# Sandbox for Proposed Challenges

Tags: discussion, sandbox

This "sandbox" is a place where Code Golf users can get feedback on prospective challenges they wish to post to main. This is useful because writing a clear and fully specified challenge on your first try can be difficult, and there is a much better chance of your challenge being well received if you post it in the sandbox first.

**[Sandbox FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056/3808)**

### Posting

To post to the sandbox, scroll to the [bottom of this page](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#show-editor-button) and click "Answer This Question". Click "OK" when it asks if you really want to add another answer.

Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it, though you can optionally add a title at the top. You may also add some notes about specific things you would like to clarify before posting it. Other users will help you improve your challenge by rating and discussing it.

When you think your challenge is ready for the public, go ahead and [post it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and **replace the post here with a link to the challenge and delete the sandbox post.**

### Discussion

The purpose of the sandbox is to give and receive feedback on posts. If you want to, feel free to give feedback to any posts you see here. Important things to comment about can include:

- Parts of the challenge you found unclear
- Comments addressing specific points mentioned in the proposal
- Problems that could make the challenge uninteresting or unfit for the site

You don't need any qualifications to review sandbox posts. The target audience of most of these challenges is code golfers like you, so anything you find unclear will probably be unclear to others.

If you think one of your posts requires more feedback, but it's been ignored, you can ask for feedback in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). It's not only allowed, but highly recommended! Be patient and try not to nag people though, you might have to ask multiple times.

**It is recommended to leave your posts in the sandbox for at least several days, and until it receives upvotes and any feedback has been addressed.**

### Other

**[Search the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=inquestion%3A2140) / [Browse your pending proposals](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=inquestion%3A2140+user%3Ame)**

The sandbox works best if you sort posts by [active](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top).

To add an inline tag to a proposal, use shortcut link syntax with a prefix: `[tag:king-of-the-hill]`. To search for posts with a certain tag, include the name in quotes: `"king-of-the-hill"`.

Answer (score 56):

> **Note:** If you are seeing this first, you might want to [sort by active](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc).

## Count the pips in a pair of dice

[Moved here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16588/11006)

Comment: a) Either one or two dice seems fine to me. b) You should be able to upload the zip file into a Gist on GitHub. c) As far as I can, this *is* a code challenge and not a code golf. The golf score seems negligible in comparison to the accuracy score, and will probably serve mostly as a tie breaker. (And I think that's good.)

Comment: (b) Maybe you could post your script in addition.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good points. I'll re-tag this as a code challenge. I'm trying to come up with a scoring system that prefers innovative hacks over long-winded but 100% correct solutions; if you can suggest any improvements then please do. I've just generated a set of sample images. In most of them, the two dice are non-overlapping, so it should be possible to score reasonably well without going overboard on the segmentation.

Comment: @TheBestOne The Python script doesn't do anything exciting. It just places two dice in the camera's field of view with randomly selected faces pointing up, then gives then a random z-axis rotation from 0 to 2π (repeating the process if the two bounding boxes intersect). I added a little devilry at the post-processing stage (pincushion distortion, glare FX and depth of field blurring) to better simulate the output of a real camera and foil solutions that expect images with perfect geometry, but none of this takes place in the Python script.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I meant so that people can generate more test cases if 100 isn't enough.

Comment: You could post 1000 cases and then announce the subset of 100 that will be used for scoring.

Comment: Can we assume these are all standard dice, so any two opposite faces add up to 7? This would allow double checks such as 3 and 4 can never be on adjacent faces, and 6 and 1 can never be on adjacent faces.

Comment: If the handedness/chirality of the dice is also guaranteed to be consistent then identifying 2 visible faces will uniquely determine the 3rd visible face, as a double check or to fill in unreliable data. I think it's worth stating explicitly whether the dice will be of consistent handedness. People can of course work this out for themselves by examining the image set, but it would be good to know for certain whether that is meant to be a reliable feature of the images.

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, they would be standard right-handed dice. I can't see the point in announcing a subset of images for testing, since this would only benefit latecomers

Comment: Ooo... a clustering algorithm question, this I like +1.

Comment: JPEG is an image format which is very hard to read when not using a special library. "Divide the size of the program by 100" is not a good idea when allowing programs having less than 50% correctness: A program simply writing random numbers will already have something about 10% correctness and its possible to do this within less than 1000 bytes (-> positive score); a program really evaluating images surely will need more than 10000 bytes (-> negative score).

Comment: Seems like a perceptron could do the trick

Comment: See also: http://www.markfickett.com/stuff/artPage.php?id=389

Comment: and: https://www.dropbox.com/s/buyg5swn0o0und2/SnakeEyesFinalPres.pptx?dl=0#

Comment: Do you know about the Secret Santa's Box?

Comment: @user202729 No. What's that?

Comment: @user202729 OK, done :-)

Answer (score 36):

### Waving Hands bot

This is a sketch for a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) contest for a game which is much more complicated than the previous questions in this genre. Implementing the test framework will be a lot of work and it will require a lot of debugging, so I want to get feedback on whether the game is too complicated before I start work on that.

---

Waving Hands (original known as Spellbinder) is a two-player simultaneous-turn-based strategy game. At one level it is quite simple. You have two hands. Each turn you perform an action with each hand. Sequences of actions performed with the same hand create spells, which have varied effects.

The first level of complication comes from the number of spells: 42. I don't intend to reproduce a list: there is an online [rules page](http://www.gamecabinet.com/rules/WavingHands.html) (which is backed up by archive.org should that fallback be necessary).

The second level of complication comes from the interactions between the spells. This is where debugging of the test framework is most likely to be needed. My plan is to allow complaints about the framework's implementation of the rules for a period of two or three weeks or until there are three posted answers, whichever is the later.

At each turn the bot will be provided with a full history (except for moves which the rules say it can't see, which will be so indicated). However, it will not be provided with any other identifying information about its opponent. I think that it will be hard to fingerprint some bots, although probably not all.

The framework will probably be written in Java and hosted on github. I intend to provide one or two wrapper classes for non-JVM languages, and a "bot" which brings up a UI for human play, which will be useful for debugging and testing your own bot.

Under the label of fair play, it will be forbidden to attempt to interfere with the opponents or access their memory. A bot may store information about the current game, to save recomputing it each move, but it may not persist information between games. Competitors may submit more than one bot, but they must be independent: i.e. no submitting bots whose purpose is to help your favoured bot win.

To reassure anyone who's worried about copyright: the creator of the game [has stated](http://mud.co.uk/richard/spellbnd.htm)

> I retain full rights to the game, and if any commercial incarnation appears then I want a royalty! I have no objection to people implementing or running derivatives of the Spellbinder so long as they make no money from it, though.

---

Normally upvotes in the sandbox indicate that you think the question is ready to post. This one clearly isn't. However, please upvote it if you think that the outlined proposal would make a good question. If there's enough support, I will create a separate sandbox answer when the test framework is ready for early criticism.

Comment: Is this intended as a short-term, deadlined competition, or will you be posting new results as submissions come in? I imagine for a contest like this, it may take a while to get something robust. Sounds fun, though!

Comment: @Geobits, I believe in updating the accepted answer when a better answer comes along.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this game - I'm creating a revamped version and my friends and I at school are all having a great time testing/playing it ;)

Comment: http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/ is [almost?] identical to Waving Hands, with an actually implemented human-vs-human version of the game.

Comment: @Sparr, see also http://games.ravenblack.net/rules/0/index.html (which I'm sure *used* to say that it was Waving Hands with no disclaimers about being a variant)

Comment: Having seen a number of very complex KotH, I've changed my mind about their suitability and no longer plan to pursue this.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I still think this one is suitable, because it is possible to start with rather naive strategies (since output is merely two characters each turn) and then gradually build on that to use more interesting strategies. If you're just not willing to expend the effort to implement the controller, I'd be interested in doing that some day, but first I've still got two other KotH proposals lying around (which don't even have as low an entry barrier as this one).

Comment: Should a bot be eliminated from the rest of a tournament if it dies?

Comment: @TheBestOne, as I say in an earlier comment, I now think this is too complex to be a good KotH, but if I were taking it forward then my answer would be, "By no means!" KotH should be round robins rather than elimination brackets to minimise the non-determinism.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe you should make a challenge that is simply to implement the game such that it can be played by two human players. Perhaps don't make it code-golf, though.

Comment: @mbomb007, I'm not sure what other winning criterion that variant could use.

Comment: Maybe just make it code-challenge. I think that if the game is implemented, it should be readable. After all, the game seems to be challenging enough. We don't need to throw in "make this as small as possible" as well. Debugging would be easier, too, since it's for human players, so testing is harder.

Comment: @mbomb007, [tag:code-challenge] isn't a winning criterion: it's an umbrella so that questions with non-standard winning criteria still have a tag.

Comment: Then just make it so the first solution wins.

Answer (score 30):

## Conquer the Solar System

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Here is an outline for a strategical King-of-the-Hill challenge which is loosely based on [Risk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)) (loosely enough so as not to preclude a future Classic Risk KotH).

It is far from complete, but I'm posting it here to gather feedback from the community to finalise the rules before getting down to implementing the control program. This would definitely make for one of the more complicated KotHs and I'd like it to be as fun as possible, so that it's worth the participants' time! I will probably leave this up for several weeks before starting work on the controller.

I wanted to try something new: **The distinguishing feature** of this challenge is that it does not use simultaneous turn-based simulation, but rather something similar to Final Fantasy X's Conditional Turn-Based Battle system. Different actions take different amounts of time, and it's simply your turn again when that time has elapsed. Of course, the control program will simply skip ahead to the next scheduled event.

There are probably more technical details in this post than what will be necessary for participants of the final challenge (and will most likely be presented in a different form then). I just wanted to include everything I've currently got, so people might point me towards issues in the underlying assumptions.

### The Setting

The year is 2200: Mankind has spread out over the entire solar system. But we all know how much humans like other humans with different resources – interplanetary war has broken out. Each inhabited planet or natural satellite – collectively referred to as (celestial) bodies – starts out as one faction in this war. The goal is conquer as much of the solar system as possible.

### The Model

The arena of the challenge is hence the solar system. I will include all solid planets and natural satellites with a diameter of 10 km or more (just for a bit of realism; this should provide a large enough surface area to build a base). There are 89 of those bodies – I could add even smaller objects should I get more submissions than that, but I think that's near impossible.

<sub>**Note:** I said "solid" bodies. Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune are gas giants and hence cannot be landed on (their satellites can be, though).</sub>

Planetary motion *will* be simulated, although in a simplified manner. Orbits are assumed to be circular and lie all in one plane, with a radius of approximately their real-life semi-major axis, and their real-life orbital period. Hence, no gravity is simulated – only simple (uniform) circular motion.

Satellite motion *will not* be simulated. Travel distances between satellites or between a planet and its satellites are assumed to be fixed (and will be determined once, by me, dependent on the satellites' orbit sizes).

The asteroid belt between Mars and Jupiter can be travelled to, but no bases can be built there – it acts mainly as a hideout. It is modelled as a continuous ring at fixed distance from the sun with fixed orbital period. Bots can choose to land their units at any position on the belt. Individual asteroids are *not* modelled – not even the larger ones like Ceres, which are way above the size limit.

Technically, the map is a complete graph whose vertices are the above 89 bodies plus the asteroid belt. The travel times between any pair of bodies depends on their distance at the time the travel commences (neglecting motion of the target during the travel). As planetary motion is simulated these travel times do generally change over time though. The future spacecraft is assumed to travel between 500,000 and 1,000,000 m/s and travels in straight lines, giving time scales between 10 seconds and 80 days.

For each match, the solar system will start out in a random configuration (each planet getting a random position on its orbit). Of course, that's not realistic, because the planetary configuration for 2200 is not going to be subject to change, but we need to keep the game fair.

### Gameplay

- Each player starts with a **base** on a random body. The remaining bodies will be uninhabited.
- Each player starts with **one flagship**, and ***n* fighters** (where *n* needs to be determined, but I'm thinking on the order of 10) – collectively referred to as *units*.
- Players write a bot that is asked for a move whenever one of their own units is idle or needs to act, because it's being attacked or similar.
- Fighters are a lot faster than flagships, so they will act as scouts as well, to avoid time-wasting travel with the flagship.
- Flagships can build new bases on uninhabited bodies, or take over enemy bases (the former taking longer than the latter).
- Each additional base immediately grants another *n* fighters.
- Each base regularly spawns new fighters (say, once a week). If a player controls an entire planet system (the planet and all satellites), the spawn rate on all bodies in that system is increased (to, say, once every five days).
- Flagships are vulnerable while working on bases. Either they can't interrupt the building process upon arrival of enemies, or such an interruption will cause the total build time to increase.
- Upon landing on a body, units can't leave immediately. They need to remain for *p* % of the time it took to get there (*p* ≈ 10?) in order to refuel. Technically, this is to prevent units from hiding all the time in interplanetary space. **(formula subject to change)**
- If there are units from multiple players on a body, they may engage in combat (see next section for details on combat).
- **If a player's flagship is defeated they immediately lose the game!** All their units and bases go over to the player who killed the flagship.
- The bot may always decide to wait idly (I'll set a minimum on this, to prevent bots from spamming the control program with millisecond waits). Waiting will be interrupted by any relevant event like allies or enemies arriving somewhere.

### Combat System

- Fights are carried similar to the rules of [Risk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)#Attacking). Please refer to the Wikipedia page or *the internet* for the exact rules for now – all necessary rules will be part of the final challenge post though.
- Attackers may choose to attack with 1 to 3 units, defenders choose to defend with 1 or 2 units. The outcome is determined by rolling dice. After each round of battle, battle may either continue with the remaining units or be aborted.
- One round of combat takes *1 day*. (subject to change)
- Whether a player is *attacker* or *defender* depends on whether he has a base on the current body. This means that two attackers could be fighting each other on an unclaimed body, in which case both may use 3 units in a fight, but units from both sides die in a tie.
- If a player has a flagship on the body where the fight takes place, one unit will roll a d8 instead of a d6, *unless* they are currently working on a base (building one or converting one).
- When players lose units, they always lose fighters first. Hence, if a player has a flagship on a planet, and loses less than all of his units, the flagship will remain.

### Implementation

I will either go with [Rusher's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/survival-game-create-your-wolf) of writing a Java controller where participants only need to implement an interface (and provide a wrapper for non-Java submissions) or I'll write a controller that invokes bots as separate processes whenever its their turn.

On their turn, each bot will be provided with

- the current time
- the number of bases and units controlled by each player
- the state of all bodies the player currently has units or bases on
- the ID and location of the idle unit(s) that can currently perform an action
- a list of all bodies with their current positions (in Cartesian coordinates, so distances can easily be determined)

  - potentially I'll just provide a list of travel times for each idle unit instead, to save the bots the need to compute those
- a list of all bodies with their current angular positions

The latter can safely be ignored, but is provided for bots that want to predict planetary motion to take shortcuts. Static numerical data like orbital radii and periods will not be provided to the bots, but I'll publish a table with the challenge to be hardcoded into the bots if desired.

### Further Design Decisions

I realise that there is a lot of complexity in this. This is why I need your help to refine the concept and remove unnecessary details while keeping the heart of the challenge in tact (while making sure the rules are consistent). Please give me all the feedback you can think of, but here are a few particular questions I have in mind that need to be answered:

- How should vulnerability during base-building be modelled? By penalising or by disallowing interruptions?
- How can fights between more than two parties be handled?
- Is the "refuelling" necessary/useful? Do the details for it need work?

In any case, I don't doubt this challenge will remain fairly complex when finalised. It might help to gather some momentum if a few heroes volunteered up front to submit a bot to this - ideally ones which show that the entry barrier doesn't need to be as high as it looks.

Anyway, thanks a lot for reading this and helping out with the design of this challenge!

I'm happy to discuss details in chat (The Nineteenth Byte or Golf/Puzzle Lab; but ping me so I know you've posted there) or just here, but this challenge may need more discussion than fits in comments.

Comment: Defending player gets, *"Planet X is under attack by Y enemy units. Will you `Defend`, `Leave`, or `SplitYourForce`."* Obviously the defender doesn't have the option to wait (because you are under attack whether you like it or not), and it doesn't really make sense for defending forces to "join".

Comment: If A takes over a base/flagship of B, what happens to the fighters of B? Are they given back to B, are they lost or are they given to A?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I've still got to edit in the most recent changes, but a flagship will be your "king", so if you lose it you die. Hence, if a flagship is killed, everything (units and bases) from B goes over to A (except his flagship, which will vanish - otherwise that would create a few situations I don't want). If you just take over a base, nothing happens to the units. More likely than not, B won't even have units on that body any more.

Comment: @ProgramFOX edited the draft

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yes to both. At the beginning of each round you can use all units present on the body, whether they arrived/spawned before the fight started or during the most recent round of fighting doesn't matter.

Comment: "Should bots have full information about the game?" - Things you could hide: which fighters are where, if a player is building a base but it has not yet been completed. (For an element of surprise.) Things you can show: the amount of bases each player has, eventually with locations. (This allows players to determine who to attack and when.) Additionally, I think it might be a good idea if a player can place one or more fighters on an otherwise unoccupied planet and that the planet would not be his in that case, but the fighters can defend the planet to stop others from taking it over.

Comment: Perhaps you could require that at least one fighter is present at a planet, and that the flagship will bring in the "building material" for the base? Another idea: the flagship can transport troops, or be accompanied by fighters. "How should vulnerability during base-building be modelled?" - When a flagship is building a new base and it is attacked, if there are any of your units on the planet that are not involved in the fight, the base can continue to be built.

Comment: However, the building process cannot be completed as long as the planet is under attack; the final step, "raising the flag in the pole", cannot be executed if there are enemy troops attacking. If noone is building on the base (or waiting to raise the flag), the base will decay twice the rate it was constructed. If the flag ship leaves, the base will be destroyed.

Comment: @user2428118 I have to tell people the *number* of fighters on a body for them to make any informed decisions about attacking it or not. Any further identity of fighters is meaningless anyway. I could keep the exact distribution of fighters from them for planets they don't currently have units or bases on, though. In any case they need to know the number of bases and units each player controls to determine the leading player, which I think is very important information for certain strategies. The reason I'm considering full information is just to make the game it bit simpler.

Comment: As for placing fighters on unoccupied planets, that is definitely intended to be possible. I'm not sure having to leave one fighter behind will accomplish anything. It's necessary in Risk because no territory can ever be unoccupied (as there are no rules for claiming such a territory), but here it seems quite pointless, because you can always claim planets without units or convert the bases on them. So I think it should be up to the players if they want to abandon their bases or not.

Comment: The flagship introducing additional troops seems to complicate things even further, and I think the d8 bonus should be sufficient to want the flagship around in an important battle. Building the base while the fight continues (as long as the flagship doesn't take part) was my intention anyway. I like the idea of "raising the flag" being only possible when the base is not under attack any more, but I'll have to think about the implications. Having the base decay sounds like a valid option too, although I think decaying at the building rate or even slower is sufficient.

Comment: The base being destroyed if the flagship leaves sounds a bit harsh but it would eliminate the problem of another flagship arriving and not being able to start a new base because there is a half-finished one already there. Thanks for your input, I'll give this some thought and work it into the specification!

Comment: I'd like to point out that orbital motions of just *two* bodies is really hard to ensure conservation of orbit for more than a few dozen orbits, most particularly when using xyz-coords. Jumping up to 100 is going to be a pain to track that. It might be easier to move the planets in r-phi plane (since only 1 of those changes) and convert those to xy coords.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm fully aware of that, and that's exactly what I was going to do (that's what I meant by the second paragraph in "The Model"). But thanks for the concern. :) (Also there are only 8 bodies whose orbits will be "simulated" at all, because satellites are basically assumed to be a cloud around their planet.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, there's no benefit to fighters hiding in interplanetary space, as their only function is to attack and defend planets. And the flagship already has a reason to stay on planets. So perhaps the refueling is unnecessary?

Comment: @James_pic I was thinking you might be able to (ab)use it store your units safely until there is something to do for them. I'll have to think about that. Especially with full information it might actually simplify things to remove the refuelling. Thanks for the suggestions, I think I'll bring this up in the chat room.

Comment: Where's the chat room? I'm interested.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte

Comment: How does a fight last one day? Do you mean that results are "rolled" and then a one-day timer starts, or that the program actually "rolls" the fight for the entire day? (like, hundreds of dice)

Comment: @Hankrecords I meant the former (or maybe the dice are rolled at the end of the day, but I can't tell right now if it makes a difference).

Comment: @MartinEnder I suppose the only thing that makes a difference is when you tell the players (those involved and those not, but I think those not involved in the fight should not know the outcome before those involved)

Comment: @MartinEnder Maybe it would be better to use rounds as a time unit rather than days, and at the end of every whole round (once every player has ended their turn), before the next one starts, you check if there's any fight that has just ended, you roll the results and inform everybody of the outcome

Answer (score 24):

## King of the Hill- Simple RPG

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Your challenge is to make a bot that plays a simple RPG game against other bots.

## The Rules of the Game

### The Board

The board is a 500x500 2-dimensional array of cells. In any cell, there is one of the following:

- Nothing.
- An obstacle. Cannot be occupied by anything.
- A player.
- A monster.

### Mechanics

Each turn, a player can:

1. Move: you can move north, east, west, or south, or not move at all. **Attempting to move into an obstacle, or off the edge of the board, will result in you not moving at all.**
2. Perform a special attack: you can either perform a ranged attack, an area attack, or no special attack at all.
3. Battle: if you encounter an enemy, you can fight them.

### Combat

Whenever you enter a square that is already occupied by a monster or another player, you fight them. You and your opponent take turns attacking each other, with the first move being decided randomly. At any point in the combat, you may flee. Also, *once per battle*, you may use a special attack which does double damage.

Damage is calculated using this formula:

Damage = Attacker's attack modifier + Random number from 1 to 5 - Defender's defence modifier

### Special Attacks

There are two special attacks: A ranged attack, that targets any enemy within 5 squares, and an area attack, that targets *all* enemies within 2 squares. Damage is calculated using the same formula as for melee damage.

### Monsters

In the game, there are 5 monsters:

1. Goblin. Attack: 1; Defence: 1; HP: 1; moves randomly; 1XP for killing.
2. Orc: Attack: 3; Defence: 2; HP: 5; follows players; 5XP for killing.
3. Troll: Attack: 5; Defence: 2; HP: 10; moves randomly; 10XP for killing.
4. Giant: Attack: 10; Defence: 5; HP: 15; follows players; 50XP for killing.
5. Dragon: Attack: 20; Defence: 10; HP: 20; follows players; 100XP for killing.

If you kill another player, you receive 100XP.

### Attributes

When you create your bot, you must give it 5 attributes. They are:

- Attack: your attack bonus when using a melee attack.
- Ranged Attack: your attack bonus when using a ranged attack.
- Area Attack: your attack bonus when using an area attack.
- Defence: your defence bonus.
- Constitution: added to your HP (10 by default).
  **Note: If your bot's constitution is -10, it dies immediately.**

These attributes must sum up to 12. They may be anywhere between -10 and 22.

## Implementation

```
public class MyBot extends RpgBot
{
    public static final int ATTACK = <insert here>;
    public static final int RANGED_ATTACK = <insert here>;
    public static final int AREA_ATTACK = <insert here>;
    public static final int DEFENCE = <insert here>;
    public static final int CONSTITUTION = <insert here>;
    // you can add something here
    public MyBot() { super(); }
    public Move move() {
        // insert here: return either Move.NORTH, Move.EAST,
        // Move.WEST, Move.SOUTH, or Move.NO_MOVE.
    }
    public SpecialAttack makeSpecialAttack() {
        // insert here: return either SpecialAttack.RANGED,
        // SpecialAttack.AREA, or SpecialAttack.NONE.
        // For ranged attacks, use setTargetX() and setTargetY()
        // to set the target beforehand.
    }
    public Attack attack(Entity m) {
        // insert here: return either Attack.NORMAL,
        // Attack.SPECIAL, or Attack.FLEE.
        // Entity m is one of the monster entities.
    }
}
```

Here are the additional functions you get for your convenience:

`Entity surroundings(int x, int y)`- returns an entity representing what is located at that point. `x` and `y` range from -5 to +5, with 0, 0 being the square where you are. Trying to access outside that range will result in an `Exception` being thrown. `Entity` is one of:

- `Entity.NONE`- nothing.
- `Entity.OBSTACLE`- an obstacle or the edge of the map.
- `Entity.PLAYER`- either you or another player.
- `Entity.GOBLIN`- a goblin.
- `Entity.ORC`- an orc.
- `Entity.TROLL`- a troll.
- `Entity.GIANT`- a giant.
- `Entity.DRAGON`- a dragon.

At the beginning of the game, the field is randomly populated with 300 obstacles, 1000 goblins, 500 orcs, 100 trolls, 50 giants, and 10 dragons.

`void setTargetX(int x)` and `void setTargetY(int y)`- set the target x and y indexes of the ranged weapon. Indexes range from -5 to 5, with 0, 0 being your location. Passing these functions an index outside the range will result in an `Exception` being thrown.

## Winning Condition

The winner is the bot that acquires the most XP before it dies.

Comment: That sounds very nice. Just to clarify, the area of effect of the area attack is a 5x5 square and the range attack can target any entity I see? Do the chasing monsters stop chasing me when I don't see them anymore? And a fixed arena size might be problematic, because it makes a vastly different game depending on how many participants there are.

Comment: @m.buettner Yes, the effect of the area attack is a 5x5 square (but of course, you don't hit yourself). The sight ranges of all monsters are the same as yours. And there is only one of each bot participating in a game, so there won't _really_ be a difference.

Comment: I don't know. If there are 5 participants, I might try to hunt for dragons and kill as many as possible. If there are 50 participants, it's unlikely that I'll meet any of them anyway, so I might be able to ignore them completely in my bot. I think the strategies might well differ depending on the monsters/bots ratio.

Comment: Will the current number of surviving players be provided to the player each turn, or will the player just have to work with what is visible from the current position?

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yes, they will only know what is visible.

Comment: Can't you just min-max with -10 ranged, -10 area, -9 const, +1 melee, +40 defense just tank an enemy until it dies? Even +35 attack would still deal no damage against +40 defense, even with a roll of 5. If this is allowed and not patched, I preemptively claim this solution for myself.

Comment: @archaephyrryx So do you think disallowing stats above +20 would be a good idea in that case?

Comment: It's up to you whether to go that route or not, but in general consider pathological cases (edge cases) to see what those would lead to. If certain cases have consequences that you did not intend to be possible or are not acceptable to you, you may want to modify the conditions; if they are intended or permissible/acceptable, you may want to leave the conditions unmodified. Also, you should consider the question as to whether defense can be negative, and examine the consequences of having negative defense.

Comment: @Alex Are you still developing this?

Comment: @Manu Yes, but I haven't been able to work on it for a rather long while.

Comment: @Alex Cool, looking forward to the challenge:)

Comment: I'd enjoy this o.o

Comment: Are you still developing this?

Comment: @Alex Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 20):

## [Build a golfing language with me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162093/66833)

Comment: Although I'd personally enjoy such a challenge, I am afraid that the sub-tasks have little to no interaction between each other, so the post might be closed as off-topic for being a [multi-part challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/59487), albeit the  presence of the tag [tag:multiple-holes]. How are you going to enforce *It doesn't aim to complete one of the sample challenges in one command*? Other than that, I don't think the winning criterion makes much sense here. Imo the answer that *breaks* the chain should win.

Comment: As per [Martin Ender's suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43488884#43488884), I've added concise descriptions for the first 12 challenges, but I don't have time to finish the rest at this very moment. I feel like the post should be self-contained, having to read so many separate challenges is quite annoying. Feel free to rollback / edit according to your preferences.

Comment: Added simple descriptions for the rest of the challenges.

Comment: "It doesn't aim to complete one of the sample challenges in one command" seems a bit easy to work around. For example, you could make a command to output `ello, World!` without breaking this rule, or to store `Hello, World!` in a variable without printing it, etc. If you try to ban this, finding the right place to draw the line will probably be hard.

Comment: Also, I'm personally not a fan of the two week cutoff, and I was under the impression that time-limited challenges were a bit of an old-school thing that people don't really do any more. It prevents people from participating if they join the game late, and for no good reason. (By the way I like this challenge idea a lot.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Regarding the two week end, every answer-chaining has to have *some* way of preventing it from continuing ad infinitum. Answers can (and should) still be posted afterwards, just with the addendum that they can't win.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing maybe there should just be no winner. Then people won't be discouraged from continuing after one is declared

Comment: @dylnan [Challenges must have a winner to be on-topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8135/66833)

Comment: You can still have an objective scoring criterion but not declare a winner. You can decide to forgo meta discussions anyway.

Comment: "every answer-chaining has to have some way of preventing it from continuing ad infinitum" <--- why? And why would that apply to answer-chaining and not any other kind of challenge?

Comment: Or another way to put it: your challenge already has a natural cutoff, namely the point where no more golfing is possible (i.e. one of the test challenges can be done in zero bytes and the rest in one byte each, if not before that point). It seems more natural and more fun to let it continue until it reaches that point, rather than cutting it off artificially.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't see that saying that challenges must have a winner, just that you must be able to objectively score yourself.  "And the interesting thing that the score alone is enough to create this motivation - there doesn't even need to be competition".

Comment: I'd go for "output the sign" vs "sum of 1-n", since you haev another "sum the input" challenge.

Comment: Is the challenge itself going to include a base-level answer to every task, or will the first answer need to come up with 2 commands that are sufficient to solve every task (since no other commands would exist yet) as well as actually making those solutions?

Comment: @KamilDrakari I'm currently working on a (almost finished) base interpreter, which will include a base level solution to each task, which I will post as the first answer.

Comment: The total minimum bytes is 20 as far as I can tell. A quine will have to be 2 bytes, and the only 0 byte program can output `Hello, World!` as that golfs two challenges. Everything else can be 1 byte, though it will probably get soft-locked at 21 bytes

Comment: "you must edit in the golf" ==> [what if the answerer deletes their account? what if they're inactive? doesn't seem like a very good solution]

Comment: @user202729 Obviously, if the user isn't active on the site, for whatever reason, they don't have to edit in the golfs. That rule is mainly in place to prevent people from posting Lenguage-esque solutions to make it easier for the next answerer.

Comment: But the scores are strictly decreasing anyway...

Comment: Ok, I know I'm late for this comment since you already put a lot of work into the interpreter, but I think it would have been more interesting having an initial language with very few/no commands, incapable of solving the given challenges, and letting answerers either golf previous solutions or make new challenges solvable. As it is right now this feels more like "golf this golfing language" than "build a golfing language"

Comment: @Leo While I do like that idea, I think that it's quite a different challenge to this one, so am going to stick to the current format. However, I, for one, would greatly enjoy a challenge like that, so feel free to make one if you want to.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. Well, if this challenge turns out to be well received that can be an idea for a follow up :)

Answer (score 19):

## DTMF Decoder

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [audio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) ([dsp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dsp)?)

---

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/66a3aDTMFpad.jpg/320px-66a3aDTMFpad.jpg

Our spies have intercepted super-secret codes being sent to the enemy in [some archaic code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling)! Can YOU decode the captured signals and save the republic?

Find the audio clips at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/nicktimko/dtmfpuzzle) or in this [repo ZIP (7 MB)](https://github.com/nicktimko/dtmfpuzzle/archive/master.zip).

Each audio file is 8 kHz and 16-bit, provided in both WAV format and text where each line is one sample. Each file contains 30 tones, each no shorter than 100 ms and with an inter-symbol gap also no shorter than 100 ms of "silence" (subject to noise). The `testtones.wav` file contains all digits, each 200 ms long, separated by 200 ms.

For reference, each of the symbols/tones/keys/digits is comprised of two superimposed sine waves:

[image: DTMF Table]

The difficulty increases as the files progress, with ever-increasing amounts of noise present. `level01.wav` is basically perfect (except for unavoidable quantization noise), `level02.wav` starts at a signal to noise ratio of 10, and `level08.wav` has a SNR of about 1 (equal parts signal/noise). The last file (`level16.wav`) has a signal to noise ratio of approximately 3%, pretty awful, but I *think* the theoretical limit is down at about 0.1%. That may be the case only if you know the symbol timing, however, and here the symbols are of variable length.

Your score is the highest level file you can decode without error, with additional tiebreaker points for tones successfully decoded from the next higher difficulty.

---

- Generate your own DTMF WAV file (might use this for a test file, or convert this to text if needed): http://www.audiocheck.net/audiocheck_dtmf.php
- Play with buttons (they like to get stuck on...): http://onlinetonegenerator.com/dtmf.html
- Cheat and use a web resource: http://dialabc.com/sound/detect/index.html (works up to about level 8, no, you can't actually use this.)

Comment: Nice idea. If you want to make it code golf, I'd probably leave out all the fanciness and require 100% accuracy. If you want to include additional and varying amounts of noise and phase shifts, I think this should rather be a code challenge and you'd need to provide a large benchmark set of audio files to test against.

Comment: @MartinBüttner if it was a code-challenge, would I do that with N gradiations of noise (sets of test files, or maybe just a big one) and the "score" would be what's the worst you can handle? Maybe a single long file (hundreds of tones) with increasing amounts of noise, score is how many are correctly decoded?

Comment: Either that, or you include multiple difficulties, provide a hundred (say) test files with random parameters, and the score is the number of correctly recognised files.

Comment: @MartinBüttner fleshed it in a bit more as a challenge, see anything awful?

Comment: @programmer5000 noticed you want this one as well...I'll hold on to it for a little while longer. The issue I had was that I'm not sure how to convert theory--the theoretical limit of detection given a SNR and symbol length--into practice. Probably need to revisit and maybe pester folks at dsp.stackexchange.com for help with that.

Answer (score 19):

## Anarchist chess

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[image: Initial position]

Just like chess, except that instead of two opposing armies, it's a free-for-all among the pawns.

The two players alternate moves. The allowed moves are to move a pawn one square forward (if the square ahead is unoccupied); if the pawn is on its initial position, to move it two squares forward (if the two squares ahead are unoccupied), or to capture a pawn that is one square ahead diagonally. Pawns do not promote upon reaching the last row and there is no en passant. The player who is left without a legal move loses.

This is an example of an [impartial game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game).

Comment: The space of valid positions seems rather small. Is this not a solved game?

Comment: @MartinBüttner You're right, it's definitely too small as is. If I post it I'll need to make the board larger than 8x8. I don't know if the game has been previously suggested.

Comment: Oh you just made it up? I thought it was a thing. In that case, you probably don't need to be worried about it being solved but maybe about participants solving it ;)

Comment: So it's only one set of pawns and they can capture each other?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes.

Comment: OK, so this is also a combinatoric game, because captures can split it into independent subgames. Some subgames, at least, are easy to analyse. Maybe worth asking on math.se whether anyone can find a full analysis.

Comment: This is an interesting game, but unfortunately the second player will always win since he can mirror whatever move the first player makes along the vertical axis of symmetry (e.g. if P1 moves the 2nd pawn up two, then P2 moves the 7th pawn up two).

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Good observation... so for a tournament only odd-sized boards should be considered.

Comment: @feersum, That's probably a good idea, as well as increasing the board size (the current size takes <1 second to solve). Another option is to consider misère play, where the last player to move loses. Misère play is in general harder, especially since this game appears to be "wild" which is an area of ongoing research. I really think this could be a great competition once the details are ironed out.

Answer (score 18):

## Underwater Survival Game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[Lions and bears are extinct, the wolves dominate the fauna on land.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/survival-game-create-your-wolf) But in the depths of the sea the battle for survival rages on.

This is the spiritual sequel to Rainbolt's Survival Game, with a few additions. The arena is the sea and hence three-dimensional. Furthermore, you can choose one of three different species this time: write your bot as a whale, a shark or a giant squid!

### The Arena

The game is carried out on a three-dimensional grid: +*x* points East, +*y* points North, +*z* points up. There will be `20*√n` cells along *x* and *y*, where `n` is the number of participants. The height will always be 21 cells. There are five regions: three are the species' breeding grounds, and two are just non-special regions in between. The 21 layers are distributed as follows:

[image]

The board wraps around along the *x* and *y* directions but not along *z*.

Each cell will be populated by at most one animal or hazard.

### The Game

Each bot starts with 100 instances randomly distributed in its own breeding layer.

Every turn, each bot can do one of two things:

- **Move:** The move can be one cell in any orthogonal or diagonal direction (as well as staying in the same cell, which technically shouldn't be called a "move"). Moves off the board (above the top or below the bottom layer) are ignored.
- **Breed**: Each animal starts with a breeding counter at 100 which is decremented every time step if it's greater than 0. If the counter is zero *and* the animal is in its species' breeding ground, there is a 10% chance that a new animal will spawn on a random (orthogonally or diagonally) adjacent cell - this new animal will simply be a new instance of your bot. If this happens, the breeding counter is reset to 10.

If two animals or hazards move to the same cell they fight until only one of them remains. If more than two animals (or hazards) move the same cell, two of them are picked randomly for a fight until there is only one survivor left. For details on fighting see below.

Your animal will be provided with the arena size, a 3x3x3 map showing its immediate surroundings, its breeding counter and its global *z* coordinate.

The winner will be bot with the most specimen (instances) surviving after 1000 rounds.

### The Species

Your choice of animal determines where in which layer of the arena your animals can breed (see *The Arena*) and will give you one distinct skill:

- **Whales** (`W`) start with 10% more specimen.
- **Sharks** (`S`) can make an additional *Move* before their regular action. They will receive their updated surroundings after the first move. The first move must be made into an empty cell or it will be ignored.
- **Squid** (`Q`) can see further and are provided with a 5x5x5 map of their surroundings.

### The Hazards

Each layer has a distinct type of hazards which will "play" along the bots.

**Fishing nets** (`N`) sweep through the whales' breeding grounds. They will stretch across the entire depth of the layer and have the following pattern in the *x*-*y* plane:

```
N     N
NN   NN
 NNNNN
  NNN
```

They constantly move in the *+y* direction. About half of the nets will point and move in the opposite direction.

**Jellyfish** (`J`) are found in the sharks' breeding grounds. If there's a jellyfish adjacent to another animal, that animal cannot move (unless that animal is also a Jellyfish). Jellyfish move in alternating pattern such that it always stays in the central 3 layers of the sharks' breeding grounds: twice down, twice up. If no animal is around, they will move straight down and in a random (possibly diagonal) direction up. If there is an animal in one of the 9 cells in the current direction, the jellyfish will move to that cell (or if multiple cells are occupied will pick a random one of these).

**Mantis shrimp** (`M`) are only found on the ground (lowest *z* coordinate of the squid layer). Each turn there is a 10% chance that the shrimp will cause a cavitation bubble, which will blind all animals within a radius of 4 (Chessboard distance) for the next turn. They walk randomly but all in unison (don't ask me how they do it).

**Naval mines** (`O`) are found in the regular layers between the breeding grounds. They never move. When stepped upon, the mine explodes, killing everything within a radius of 1 (Chessboard distance) including the animal that triggered the mine.

There will be `30*n` hazards in each layer, where `n` is the number of participants. The exception are the nets. There will be `2*n` nets in the whale layer.

### The Fights

Each fight is basically a non-uniform coin flip for who survives with the following probabilities:

- If a bot picked *Breed* it always dies.
- Nets are indestructible and hence always survive.
- Jellyfish and Mantis shrimp will survive with a probability of 1/3.
- If two bots fight, the odds are 50:50; *except* if one of the participants is in their own breeding grounds, in which case their chance of survival drops to 1/3 (because animals are unalert in their breeding grounds and that totally makes sense).

### Sandbox notes

The controller has yet to be written, but I intend to do a Rainbolt-style KotH where you can *either* implement an abstract Java class *or* write a command-line script.

All numbers in the spec are subject to change until the challenge is actually posted.

I'm pretty sure the spec is currently incomplete (of course I/O is missing, but that has to wait until the controller is written), but currently I can't see the wood for the trees, so please point out the holes.

As usual, is anything unclear or could be improved? In particular, it will be hard to get the balancing right for this one, I think. I'm happy to discuss any questions or comments either here or in [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: Next task after getting a controller program written is to write a 3d visual representation to watch back interesting matches...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16028/discussion-between-githubphagocyte-and-martin-buttner).

Comment: "Shrimp always attack with scissors" How appropriate...

Comment: This challenge is old but good. I predict you'll get a lot of rep for this...

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC provided it ever happens and isn't too complicated...

Comment: @MartinEnder Yeah, it's been a couple years now...

Comment: You should post this already...

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure, are you going to write the controller? ;)

Comment: https://deeeep.io

Comment: There must be a strategy not to be involved.

Answer (score 17):

## 10-character golfing language

[language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

**{{{rewriting}}}**

Your task is to design and implement a new golfing language. The catch: it must only have 10 significant characters as commands.

## Design and Implementation rules

Your language should have the following characteristics:

- It must be [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (theoretically).
- There should be at most 10 characters (of your choice) which are significant to the program. That is, any characters other than your 10 chosen characters should have no effect on regular program execution.

  - You can choose to have these characters be removed via preprocessing or producing an error if there are any in the source code (**before** program execution; they should not be used to terminate the program early as an 11th instruction, nor be used to encoded additional information).
- Your selected characters should only consist of ASCII characters, **unless:**

  - You want to use or create a code page for your language if you desire to use characters outside of the ASCII plane. Said characters should be translated into regular bytes.
- You **should not** design an encoding to a language, existing or not. As you are *designing* a *language*, your submission must be so. Submitting a “language” which is just a fancy way of encoding a [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage) program is therefore not allowed.

  - By extension, this includes having one of your commands be an "evaluate" function that is not for the language itself. So, you can't implement "eval python" or "execute shell code" functions.
- Your language should be capable of basic input (through STDIN and/or command line arguments) and output (to STDOUT, STDERR, and/or a file).

  - You may choose to ignore any one of these I/O methods, as long as one of each is supported.
  - Implicit I/O is acceptable.

### Winning

1 week after no new answers are added, the winner is the language which completes the following tasks in the fewest total bytes.

## The Challenges

All numeric inputs and outputs can be any (consistent) base, including unary.

### 1: Greetings, Humans!

**Challenge:** Output the following text, with or without leading/trailing whitespace: `Greetings, Humans!`

**Example Output:**

```
Greetings, Humans!
```

### 2: Even cats

**Challenge:** Output every other byte of input, starting with either the first or second byte given.

**Example Input:**

```
Hello, World!
```

**Example Output 1:**

```
Hlo ol!
```

**Example Output 2:**

```
el,Wrd
```

### 3: Do the wave

**Challenge:** Given number `N`, output the first `N` lines of the following infinite wave:

```
#
 ##
   ###
      ###
         ##
           #
           #
         ##
      ###
   ###
 ##
#
#
 ##
   ###
      ###
         ##
           #
     .
     .
     .
```

### 4: Quine

**Challenge:** Write a non-empty program which outputs itself, character for character. It must be a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/).

### 5: Coprimality

**Challenge:** Given an integer \$n\$, output all integers \$k\$ coprime to \$n\$ such that \$1\le k \le n\$.

```
input, output
10, 1 3 7 9
7, 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

### 6: Ternary

**Challenge:** Given an integer `N`, output the base-3 (ternary) digits of `N`.

**Note:** You may *not* take input in base 3 for this challenge.

```
input, output
1, 1
2, 2
3, 10
4, 11
5, 12
120, 11110
250, 100021
253, 100101
254, 100102
1020, 1101210
```

### 7: Word value sum

**Challenge:** Given a string consisting of only uppercase ASCII characters (`A-Z`), calculate the sum of their positions in the alphabet (1-indexed).

```
input, output
"A", 1
"AAAA", 4
"HELLO", 52
"GOLF", 40
```

### 8: Shutters

**Challenge:** Given an integer `N`, output a triangle of height `N`, constructed according to the following algorithm:

1. The first row has `N` `/`s.
2. The second row has `N - 1` `/`s.
3. ...
4. The second-to-last row has `2` `/`s.
5. The last row has `1` `/`s.

That is, the `K`th row has `N - K + 1` `/`s.

```
input
output

1
/

2
//
/

3
///
//
/

4
////
///
//
/

10
//////////
/////////
////////
///////
//////
/////
////
///
//
/
```

### 9: Roll a die

**Challenge:** Given an optional seed (for randomness), yield a uniformly-random integer between 1 and 6.

### 10: Where am I walking?

**Challenge:** You will be given a list of at most four distinct characters representing the four cardinal directions. I will use `><^v` for the sake of example, but you may choose any other four characters. Suppose there is a point at the origin of a 2D plane. Each directional character moves this point 1 unit in that direction. Given this list, output the final destination of this point.

```
input, output
"", 0 0
">>>>>^", 5 1
">v<^", 0 0
"v>>^>v<^vv^<", 1 -1
"vvvvvvvvvvvvv<<<<<<<<<<<<<", -13 -13
```

### 11: Reproduction

**Challenge:** Write a program \$P_0\$ in your language which outputs another program \$P_1\$ in your language, which outputs another program \$P_2\$ in your language, which outputs *another* program… and so on. No two \$P_j\$ should be the same, that is, all programs generated should be distinct from each other.

**Note:** Your program *may not* read its own source code for this challenge. Standard [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) rules apply.

### 12: Product

**Challenge:** Given an optional integer `N` and `N` additional integers, output the product of those `N` integers.

```
N, ints -> output
5, 1 2 3 4 5 -> 120
1, 3 -> 3
2, 1 1 -> 1
9, 0 1 9 3 4 8 12 9 120 9 -> 0
4, 100 200 300 400 -> 2400000000
3, 91 23 84 -> 175812
```

### 13: Sort a string

**Challenge:** Given a string of printable ASCII characters (and optionally its length), sort the characters by the code points of the string. [Here](http://ascii-table.com/) is a list if you're unfamiliar with them.

```
"input" -> "output"
"hello" -> "ehllo"
"the YMCA" -> " ACMYeht"
"~..~ {_+}" -> " +.._{}~~"
"this is an example input, with some stuff!" -> "       !,aaeeeffhhiiiilmmnnoppssssttttuuwx"
```

(...more challenges to come...)

### 14: Repeat indexing

**Challenge:** Given two integers **R** and **I** and a string **S**, repeat the **I**th character of **S** **R** times. (**K** can be 0- or 1-indexed; I will use 0 here.) You may assume that index **I** exists for **S** and that **R** is non-negative.

```
R, I, "S" -> "output"
4, 1, "Hello, World!" -> "Heeeello, World!"
0, 0, "language" -> "anguage"
3, 3, "hi!" -> "hi!!!"
5, 2, "aaabbb" -> "aaaaaaabbb"
```

Comment: "Your language should be capable of basic input" - is a language that only implicitly does both (or indeed either) acceptable? (I'm guessing yes)

Comment: Quine - proper, or is say `0` a quine if it outputs `0`?

Comment: The way to win with high probability (encode Jelly) is banned, and the ban is non observable? Again? Come on, this is not quine rules...

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes to comment #1, no to #2

Comment: @user202729 I was kinda hoping that people would be able to use their _minds_ and have a bit of common sense. Come on, everyone has one...

Comment: you need at least 10 challenges (otherwise you can do a SK combinator with single commands to do each of the challenges + empty program to do another)

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Hardcoding will be a problem. I intend on having 15 challenges, along with a hidden set of 15 additional challenges to prevent hardcoding

Comment: I doubt anyone would be so cheeky as to take this as a loophole, but you should probably say explicitly that languages aren't allowed to use command-line flags to modify their behavior (or, alternately, that all solutions must use the same flags across all tasks).

Comment: @DLosc Good idea, and thanks for the grammar fix tho

Comment: 1) For the sake of challenge 6, you'll want to change "numeric I/O can be in any consistent base" to exclude I/O in ternary. 2) Suggestion: a challenge that takes two (or more) numeric inputs.

Comment: `rand=lambda seed: 4 #guaranteed to be random` (please define random)

Comment: @JoKing no? I'm pretty sure this site has a definition of random. (I distinctly remember there being at least 1 meta about randomness)

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce Thanks for the feedback, I'll simply disallow reading the program's source for that particular challenge.

Comment: So `6 if seed>5 else seed+1` is valid? [Random doesn't mean uniformly by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10923/76162)

Comment: Suggestion: A challenge mixing string and number input, e.g. repeat this string N times

Comment: @JoKing something that inane of a solution should be a standard loophole. I'll clarify

Comment: @JoKing Also, good idea

Comment: Can we submit variations/derivatives of existing languages? Or even submit an already existing language (like brainfuck) to see how well it stacks up against other submissions?

Comment: @JoKing I'm not sure. It's not a bad idea I think

Comment: I like this idea a lot and I want to see it succeed, but I think the current setup will unavoidably lead to languages with builtins (possibly multi-character ones) to solve the specified tasks. That's probably not what you want, but it looks like the unquestionable winning strategy. However, I think you can avoid this problem in the following way: *Don't base the scoring on the publicly posted tasks.* Instead, base it on a hidden set of tasks that are very similar to the public ones but just different enough that languages won't benefit from having builtins for the public ones. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Basically, the public tasks aren't the actual tasks, they're examples of what the actual tasks might look like. For example, the public task 1 is to print `Greetings, Humans!`, but the languages are scored on printing `Wassup, Homies?` (Obviously yours would be different because this example is public now!) Public task 4 is a quine, but real task 4 is some quine variant. Real task 3 is a similar "print N lines of this periodic pattern" task, but with a different pattern. Etc.

Comment: @DLosc I hinted at it [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14212?noredirect=1#comment57909_14212) but I was thinking about doing something along the lines of what you described. I will still use the real tasks as score and have the hidden set of challenges be weighted more. While I like the symmetry idea, I might opt to shake it up a bit and have more than 15 hidden challenges.

Comment: I did see that comment (you should add it to the post itself), but you'll still get builtins for the public tasks unless there are *no* points to be gained by doing so. I'm picturing stuff like "The ten 3-character programs that begin with `$q` can solve tasks 1-10." That leaves plenty of room for general-purpose syntax (thus enabling Turing-completeness and solutions for the hidden tasks), but it's still a bunch of weird special cases that don't contribute anything worthwhile to the language. IMO.

Comment: @DLosc that's fair... I could offer a large bounty/checkmark to languages which don't have builtins to incentivize fair play.

Comment: If the program is `1`, do task 1; If the program is `2` do task `2`; ...; if the program start with `99`, mapping `1` to `+`, `2` to `-`, `3` to `[`, ..., as it work in BF.

Comment: @tsh please read the above comments. this problem will be prevented using a hidden set of challenges.

Comment: Would I be allowed to have characters alias each other? For instance, maybe `>` and `3` do the same thing, but using one might be easier to read than the other. Preprocessing would, of course, normalize the value to only one of those characters.

Answer (score 16):

## Who needs a GUI anyway?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Most people like GUIs.

You don't.

They say that GUI's show them pretty pictures.

### Your task:

Write a program that displays said image in full 256-colour ANSI art in the terminal. Because you *need* to show them your leet skillz at programming, you have decided to write this as short as possible. "That's a program?" - Some user

## Challenge

- Given input from stdin or the command line of an image filename, the program must output it to stdout in [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

  - To output a string in green (#00FF00), you can print `\x1b[48;5;46mInsert text here!` where `\x1b` is codepoint 27 (hex 1b).
  - `\x1b[48;5;<bgcode>m` sets the colour.
  - At the end of each line, the colour formatting should be reset so not to make the output look ugly on terminals with a resolution higher than 80x24 set.
- Your program must support at least one of the following image file formats: PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM, SVG

  - You may use image processing libraries to parse images.
- The output must be viewable in any terminal sized over 80x24.

  - If the longest side is the x-axis, its length must be resized to 80.
  - If the longest side is the y-axis, its length must be resized to 24.
  - The aspect ratio of the image must be kept the same. Scale using `min(80/X,24/Y)`, rounding down
  - The output can be assumed to be a console that supports ANSI.
  - Each character of the resized image represents 1 pixel.
- The characters printed must be a space.
- The colour for an individual pixel must be the closest available colour in the [colour map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Xterm_color_chart.png) (Text version in wikipedia link above).

  - In this case, the similarity of 2 colours can be defined as: 
    `((R1-R2)^2+(G1-G2)^2+(B1-B2)^2)^0.5`
    where results closer to zero indicate closer similarity.
- If your image format supports the alpha channel, you may assume it is empty/doesn't exist.

### Example

[image: PPCG logo]

[Found here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/icon-48.png) is our beloved logo. [This hexdump](https://pastebin.com/SY72ygxd) is what your program should output given that image as an input.

**This is a code golf, the answer with the shortest answer in bytes wins!**

Comment: 1. Are image processing libraries allowed? Decoding the image is the most difficult part. 2. What does "closest available colour" mean? How do you calculate the distance? 3. Provide a link to a simple reference about using ANSI escaping. 4. An example is great. One is enough, unless more examples can highlight different aspects of the question. 5. should the aspect ratio be maintained?

Comment: Updated to answer 1,2,3,5. Answer to 4 upcoming.

Comment: 1. ANSI is the name of a standards institute. "In ANSI" is not very clearly expressed. 2. It's not clear why, having said that the task is about outputting arbitrary images, you suddenly start talking about printing "*Hello, World!*". 3. You seem to be assuming that each character on the terminal will correspond to one pixel, but it's not clear why. And then you say that we can use any character. Wouldn't it make more sense to leave foreground alone and just change background and write a space? 4. You've left open a classic loophole by allowing people to scale their image to 0x0 or 1x1.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Removed that reference. 2. I hope that's clearer, it was meant to explain how you can use ANSI escaping. 3. Added that explicitly. 4. Loophole closed but I'm not sure how clear it is now.

Comment: I think this would be better suited for [tag:popularity-contest] because image processing / printing may very between systems. Correct output should probably be console based to avoid giving languages like JavaScript an easy advantage. Taking in input with function argument is also common. Also, are [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example) allowed? This can make it easier for languages that don't support image processing well to participate.

Comment: If there is a clearly defined objective specification (which there appears to be) then popularity contest doesn't seem to be a good fit. If you don't have a reason to avoid golf, that seems a perfectly good fit.

Comment: @trichoplax currently discussing this in chat

Comment: The resizing rule doesn't quite work since the screen isn't square. For example, if the image is 800 by 700, then the longest side is horizontal but scaling that down to 80 still leaves the vertical at 70, which is longer than 24. I think what you want is "Scale down the image just enough to fit into 80 by 24, while maintaining the aspect ratio as closely as possible"

Comment: If you want to give an explicit method, scale an X by Y image by min(80/X,24/Y). Then you just need to specify whether fractions become the floor, ceiling or are rounded.

Comment: Grammar question - does `GUI's` need that apostrophe? I'd write `GUIs`, but I don't know the rules for abbreviations like that

Comment: @Flp.Tkc fixed. I've lost my example program over time now so I'll have to recreate one

Comment: Do you plan to post this? I'd like to do so if you don't. Also, by community guidelines I'm allowed to do so in 7 days if you don't respond to this. This is a great challenge, I'd hate to see it go to waste!

Comment: @MDXF Ping me tomorrow about it in TNB and I'll post it then :P

Answer (score 16):

## I can't believe it's not a Platypus!!!

This is an image of our wonderful <s>pet</s> platypus @Cyoce.

[image]

This is also an image of the same person, or is it?

[image]

<sub>*(hint: it isn't)*</sub>

Your task is to determine whether a inputted image is @Cyoce in disguise...

The input may be taken in any form.  It will also always be 256*256px.

You will compare the image to the top image, @Cyoce profile image.

If the image is not within 1000 units of the profile picture, you must output the phrase "I can't believe it's not platypus!!!" exactly.

A unit is decided by the following:

- If a given pixel is rgb(255,255,255) in the inputted image and rgb(250,250,250) in the martin image, it is 3 units away.  That is one unit per 5 rgb points off.  So rgb(100,120,100) vs rgb(100,100,100) is 4 units off.  Floor the units, so 255 vs 253 is just 0.
- Calculate that for each pixel, and sum the units.

If the inputted image is more than 1000 units off, output the title phrase "I can't believe it's not a platypus!!!"

## *Sandbox notes:*

- **This is in development.**
- **Test cases coming later. Feel free to provide some.**
- **If somebody has code they would like to donate to me for test case generation, please do. :P**
- **I might change the units req. to a higher number depending on how this turns out.**
- **Any other advice?**

Comment: Some images failing and succeeding the test would be cool

Comment: I know, working on test cases.  Will do tomorrow.

Comment: Haha, I like this but it does seem rather simple. If a language can only take the pixels as an array of RGB numbers it's pretty trivial (map, divide, floor, sum). Maybe it could be some kind of average so that `150 180 30` would have the same number of units as `100 120 20` (a darker shade of the same colour)? Or match rotated/flipped images?

Comment: Could you shrink the images? It looks kinda freaky scrolling through the sandbox and seeing this... (p.s. you can use the `img` tag  `<img src=... width="300" />`)

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ famous last words "will do tomorrow" lol

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala ....oops. >_> I need code to generate the test cases, haven't written it.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ haha

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Perhaps it will magically do itself in 6 to 8 weeks! :-)

Comment: You going to post this riker?

Comment: Is this ever going to get posted?

Comment: @MDXF yes, but it's not going to be soon.

Comment: @Rɪᴋᴇʀ 2 yrs later...

Comment: @ArtemisFowl hush, I'll do it eventually™...

Answer (score 15):

### Self-Golfing Code

I think it would be interesting to have a challenge to write a program where the program could "golf" itself. The hard part is coming up with the right specification and restrictions to keep the submissions interesting. What I'm currently thinking of are the following:

- The input is the program's own source code, provided in stdin or as a file.
- The output is a "golfed" version of the source code that must be shorter by at least 5 characters.
- If the "golfed" version was run with the same input (the original source code), the output must be the same as the output of the original.
- If the program was run with any other program (in the same language) as the input, the output must still be syntactically valid. It does not need to shorten it, and it does not matter if the resulting program doesn't function the same way.
- If the program's source code was placed within another program (in the same language), then running the golfer on that other program would still "golf" the embedded source code in the same way. (The idea here is to prevent something like a program that just deletes the first five characters of itself.)
- The score is the length of the original "ungolfed" program.

Is this challenge interesting enough in a variety of languages? And what other cheap tricks need to be guarded against?

Comment: It is a little interesting too me that you basically require the submitter to turn in a incompletely golfed submission. Or is this not intended to be a [code-golf]?

Comment: It's still a code-golf. That's part of the challenge - you still have to golf it but leave room so that your program can still golf itself a little more. I think it would be interesting to see what approaches people take for this.

Comment: Alternately, I could count the length of the golfed result instead of the original program, though I'm not sure it will make much difference in determining the winner.

Comment: I think I need to add a rule that prevents a simple trim() operation to eliminate whitespace at the end of a line. Would it be sufficient to say "all trim()-like operations are banned"?

Comment: why ban trim()? You force competitors to manually implement an otherwise built-in function. Besides, would "r_( )+$__" or an equivalent trivial trailing space replacement be counted?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to do about it now. I don't like having to ban a function, but trim() allows for single statement solutions where you just read in the first line and trim off 5 trailing spaces. I was hoping for a challenge that would be more interesting.

Comment: You'll need to ban comments, unnecessarily long variable names, all unnecessary whitespace... And even then I can see fairly easy cheap tricks like unnecessary variable swaps (`\\` in GolfScript). Hard to make this robust enough.

Comment: @Peter Taylor I was already planning on banning comments. I don't think replacing variable names is non-trivial, though it might be in some languages. Whitespace is a big problem, though. In the end, I agree that this question doesn't seem like it'll work out.

Comment: I think you need to add a source restriction, so that the user cannot create a gigantic program with tons of spaces then just remove a bunch. Make it so the program can only have 10 of each character or something. And maybe make the score the difference of the starting and ending programs. Then, I'd say that the output of the 2nd program doesn't have to be the same as itself, it can be even **shorter**! Then just use the eventual output of the nth program in comparison to the original.

Comment: I believe it's a tad to vague. It would be too easy to do something like (in JS for e.g.) `$$$$$$=eval(prompt().replace(/$+/g,"$"))`... unless if that's what you want, of course.

Comment: What about [tag:popularity-contest] and drop conditions about other programs. The program should take it's own code and golf it in such way, that the resulting syntax tree differs. On any input both programs should behave in the same way.

Comment: There may be a trivial loophole. Let's say that in language X xyz is a syntactically sound program that takes input, ignores it, causes no errors and outputs xyz. So a kind of a quine. Now Let's say that abcccdyz also ignores input and outputs xyz. Then xyz is the golfed version of abcccdyz, so the self golfing condition is met. If you give it another program in language X, it returns a syntactically correct program xyz. If abcccdyz is embedded in another program that you give as an input, it will give a program with xyz embedded in it, as it will be xyz itself.

Comment: It is a compiler and when it compiles it has to come up with a program to do this. Bonus points for securing a banking algorithm.

Answer (score 14):

## Global Warming [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This KOTH takes place on a melting iceberg. You must stay on it as long as possible, and preferrably, be the last man standing.

The field is a perfectly circular iceberg which shrinks at a unknown rate, in the center of a 2D plane. Gameplay is executed in turns on which your program will be called with the current status of the iceberg and other participants. Each turn you may either change your movement direction or push someone near you (or neither).

### Movement and positioning

Positioning is in a 2D plane of floating point coordinates, and movement is a speed of x and y components. When issuing a move command, your entry will keep moving in that direction until you explicitly tell it to stop or change direction with another move command (or a push, more on this soon). The maximum move speed is 1.0 in magnitude, and if you ask to move further than that, your speed will be adjusted to conform this limit.

### Pushing

Your program can issue push commands to any entity within a radius of 1 from you, resulting in you and your target having your speeds changed to point away from eachother and at a given speed. The push speed is directly adjustable, but the direction isn't. Push speed is under the same limitations as a move command, and thus can't be stronger than 1. If two people push the same target at once, the target is pushed in the resultant direction. Pushing will take into account the target's move command, if there was one.

### Input

Each round, your program will be invoked from the command line, with a CSV document being passed to its STDIN. The first line of this document provides the current iceberg radius (floating point number) and the amount of remaining competitors (integer)

After this "header", there will be one line for each remaining competitor in the following format (which is on its turn on the format `type(variable)`):

```
string(entity id),float(x),float(y),float(velocity x),float(velocity y)
```

Your entry will always be the first item on the list.

Example input:

```
12.4,2
1af3b,10.22,5.42,0.0,0.7
d5e86,-2.18,6.66,0.6,-0.2
\
```

(the \ is a trailing newline, represented like that for clarity)

### Output

Your program will process the given input and output a ASV (Anything Separated Values) document. A ASV is like a CSV, except everything that doesn't match the regex `[.0-9a-z]` is considered a separator (even uppercase letters). If your program emits more than 1 line, only the last one is considered.

For movement:

```
move,float(velocity x),float(velocity y)
```

For pushing:

```
push,string(entity id),float(strength)
```

To do nothing, simply don't output anyting

Where `move` and `push` are string literals.

Example:

```
move,0.0,0.7
```

or

```
push,d5e86
```

The following lines are valid outputs for your program:

```
moveA0.0A0.7
moveX0.0Y0.7
move!0.0:0.7
```

### Detailed Rules and remarks

A list of important points to consider:

- You can skip your turn by returning no output, but this will make you keep moving in the direction you ere headed to.
- If a competitor loses, it will not show up on the participants list (see below)
- A player is considered to fall from the iceberg if their distance from the center is greater than the iceberg's radius.
- Entries do not have a physical radius, so they cannot bump on eachother (except for the push command)
- You can't know the shrinking rate of the iceberg.

### Scoring

A entry's score is the average `turns_survived*players/total_turns` out of 10 runs. Each run may have a indefinite (but not infinite) amount of turns, until only one competitor survives.

The scores will be periodically maintained here, and 100% up-to-date at **INSERT URL**

The winner will be chosen at **INSERT DATE**

### Examples in pseudocode

**Antisocial** - pushes everyone away from him, doesn't care about where he is.

```
#!/bin/env pseudocode
data = read_csv(stdin)
foreach line in data.range(1,data[0,1]):
    if distance(me, line[1], line[2]) <= 1:
        write_csv_line(stdout, ["push", line[0], 1.0])
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the feedback!: 1. Made the format *very* flexible for a CSV. 2. Yes, the radius will evolve non-linearly and vary at runtime based on variables outside the program's reach. 3. There is no strength to a push, will clarify. It simply changes the target's speed as if it issued a `move`. 4. Yes, speeds will be normalized so they never exceed 1 in any direction (moving diagonally will not be faster).
I just updated the answer I hope it explains these points.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good point, I couldn't find a appropriate term for this (capping the net speed, not their axial components), would you direct me at a better word? (English is my second language) Players can indeed move at speeds slower than 1. Should I say "your net speed will be capped at 1"?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good point. Will update.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure about the push. What will be the resulting speed? 1? The previous speed, just rotated? In that case, I'd be immune to pushes be standing still.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good catch on standing still. I guess the push speed would be the average of yours and your target's, in the direction away from you. The idea of not moving at full speed is exactly to minimize push efficiency, but with the average I can't imagine a exploit.

Comment: Well you could also minimise its utility by making it more physically correct such that the push is applied to you as well (in the opposite direction)... conservation of momentum and such. Then you could let players choose the push strength, and they'd have to decide how strongly they want to be pushed themselves.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That would be interesting... And less of a warped reality. xD Though I do not intend do make this a completely physics-based challenge, so I guess that the direction will just set to "away from eachother". Plus, these quirks can make a really unexpected playfield.

Comment: Yes, I'd leave it at that. It would be a lot more complicated if you made it really physics based, since the velocities wouldn't change so abruptly. So you could just make a push always along the direction connecting the two players, but apply the push to both of them.

Comment: Reworded the question (answer?) to a more readable manner.

Comment: One issue that isn't addressed is what happens to me after I was pushed.  If I try to move and one or more people push me, where do I move? What if player A pushes B pushes C pushes A? Also, since you give a speed (but not distance) moved, you should list how much time is simulated between turns (1 second?)

Comment: @Zaq Totally didn't think about that. If any player is pushed by two people at once, he is stopped. About the speed, the execution will work at 1 speed per turn. Will edit this info into this answer now.

Comment: @Kroltan: Do you want to make it conform better to reality by taking the resultant direction (and speed) when a target is pushed by two people, instead of stopping it? It's weird to see that a target being pushed by two people from behind get stopped. But this is your universe, so this is up to you. =)

Comment: @justhalf I didn't want to do that because I had no idea how to, but i just realized it's dead simple to do. Sum the forces and cap to the max speed

Comment: This game (trying to push other players off of a (possibly shrinking) circular iceberg) is one of the modes in the delightful PS1 title _Crash Bash_.

Comment: @justhalf I know ;D

Comment: @Kroltan: You directed your reply to the wrong person. haha. I didn't play Crash Bash.

Comment: @justhalf OH, blame the mobile SX app! Sorry for pinging you (and now one more time)

Comment: Does a player's direction after a push take into account his movement? i.e. If a player is moving at a speed of 1 and is pushed from a direction perpendicular to his movement with a strength of 1, does his movement vector change by 45 degrees?

Answer (score 14):

## Random Golf of the Day

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

**Meta:** *I am running this as a little series of challenges revolving around the topic of randomness - in the form of a 9-hole golf course. I'm maintaining a leaderboard across all challenges in the series, and offer a large bounty to the person competing in all of them with the lowest overall score.*

*Just to be clear, despite the name, I won't be posting these once a day. Expect the next one in 6 to 8 weeks.*

## About the Series

This will be a series of 9 challenges. See [the first instalment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45302/8478) for more information about the series.

## #1: [Shuffle an Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45302/8478)

[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

## #2: [Numbers from a Normal Distribution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45447/8478)

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## #3: [Integer Partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46991/8478)

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)[integer-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions)

## #4: [The Bertrand Paradox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49394/8478)

[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

## #5: [Diamond Tilings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51222/8478)

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)[tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling)

## #6: [Roll a d20](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51222/8478)

[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

## #7: [A distinctly random character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89621/8478) (guest entry by trichoplax)

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## #8: [Shuffle an infinite list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120472/8478)

[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

## Further ideas (still unordered):

- **Poisson disc sampling:** This is a method to randomly distribute points across the plane densely while maintaining a minimum distance between points. I think this might be nice to golf. [Further reading.](http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/)
- **Generate a random chessboard:** The submissions should randomly produce a believable chessboard. "Believable" here mostly affects pawns: they may not appear on the first row of their colour, there may be more pieces of other types if pawns are missing (due to conversion), and two pawns may only be in the same column if at least one of the opponent's pieces is missing. Submissions should be able to generate any valid board with finite probability, but it doesn't have to be uniform.
- **Generate a random arithmetic expression:** This basically asks to create a tree of binary and unary operators, subject to some constraint - either on the structure of the tree (`n` nodes, say) or on the result of the arithmetic expression (generate a random expression that evaluates to a given `n`).
- **Generate a random hole-free polyomino** (or orthogonal polygon) (of given size).
- *Vague idea:* Generate points on a sphere with uniform distribution.
- *Vague idea:* I'd like to include a challenge on random walks.
- *Vague idea:* I'd like to include a challenge which has to generate a random number with a constraint based on its digits, but where you're not allowed to use strings or arrays (so you have to access the digits arithmetically).
- *Idea I'm not sure about:* Generate a valid Unicode character as a set of UTF-8 bytes with uniform randomness.
- *Idea:* Implement a (specific) PRNG.
- *Idea:* Generate a random Brainfuck program (or other balanced string). Would probably need to require uniform distribution and deterministic runtime to be interesting.

Comment: As discussed in chat, the "random partitions" doesn't require much modification of one existing answer on a partition question, although since most can't be modified so easily it's probably on the right side of the borderline. The chessboard is sure to generate controversy over the definition of "believable". The random expr seems very close to a number of existing questions which require enumeration of arithmetic expressions. The Unicode one is basically just a Kolmogorov compression of the table of assigned codepoints.

Comment: @Peter, the chessboard challenge will come with an unambiguous spec. For the arithmetic expressions, I'll make sure to check what we've already had. Unicode: hm yeah, it would definitely be one of the simpler challenges.

Comment: Idea: "reverse-engineering". Given a sequence of 1000000 random numbers from a generator of a known type (e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)), determine the next number. Have to discourage (or somehow disallow) brute-force answers.

Comment: 1. Points on a sphere with uniform distribution: I'd be surprised if you weren't aware, but dA/dz for a sphere is constant: all slices of the same thickness have the same external surface area. So all you need is a uniform distribution of longitude and a uniform distribution of z height.  2. I like the chessboard idea.

Comment: @steveverrill I wasn't aware that dA/dz is constant, but I was aware that this would be a rather simple instalment of the series. I've started to think that the chessboard challenge would be a pain to specify and to solve correctly. Currently, my favourites are the random polyomino and the Poisson disc sampling.

Comment: @anatolyg: I was working on that problem for LCGs a while back. It turns out to become an integer programming problem, and I have a suspicion it might even be NP-complete. As such, it may be that brute force is the only solution that works in general.

Comment: The "generate a random balanced string" problem isn't made much more interesting via requiring deterministic runtime and uniformity; you can just generate all balanced strings and pick one at random. It might be possible to make it viable via a complexity bound, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ais523 the last instalment is probably going to be some form of random walk, so the options still listed in the post are likely irrelevant at this point, unless I ever decide to extend this to 18 holes. Good point though.

Answer (score 13):

## Which way will the see-saw turn? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given an ASCII string of spaces, `o`s, and `O`s, balance them on a see-saw pinned at the center, and determine which way it tilts.

For example, `ooO O` represents the situation:

```
ooO O
===== 
  ^
```

A lowercase `o` has a mass of 1kg, and an uppercase `O` has a mass of 2kg. The **torque** of a weight is its mass multiplied by its distance from the center of the see-saw. If the sum of the torques on the right of the see-saw is greater, the see-saw will tilt clockwise. If the sum of the torques on the left is greater, it will tilt counterclockwise.

In the situation above, the total clockwise torque is `2 * 2 = 4`, which is greater than the total counter-clockwise torque, `1 * 2 + 1 * 1 = 3`. So the see-saw tilts clockwise.

You may choose two **fixed** output values — one for “clockwise” and one for “counterclockwise”. Your program must consistently output these values for their respective situations.

The input is a string of odd length **3 ≤ n ≤ 255**, and it is guaranteed to never be in perfect equilibrium.

Comment: *consistently. Also, [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99545/36398) (but not duplicate)

Comment: maybe you could add that the see-saw is always pinned in the middle. The answer seems trival but I like it. Is there a reason to skip equilibrium?

Comment: I'm sure that `O` isn't lower case. ;)

Comment: @Christoph I think solutions are often more interesting when they are allowed to cut corners, so I try to add some well-defined corners to cut in my problems. Often, this means allowing solutions to disregard “special” cases (such as equilibrium, even **n**, or **n = 1**, in this case.)

Comment: Hm I wonder of what solution you think :) In the way I'd answer this question there wouldn't be any major difference.

Answer (score 12):

## Digital Music Box

What are holidays without music boxes?

Your task is to implement a digital music box.  Your program will be given a reel of music such as follows:

```
Music from "The Polar Express"
By Glen Ballard and Alan Silvestri
120 lines per minute
CDEFGABCDEFGABC
...............
..O.O..O.......
...............
.......O.O.O...
...............
..O.O.O........
...............
......O..O.O...
...............
CDEFGABCDEFGABC
O.O....O.......
.O......O......
..O......O.....
....O..........
..O.O.O........
...............
..O.O..........
...............
```

Now, your program must play the music, which is straightforward.  In  this example, one line is read every 1/2 second.  If a line contains one or more `O` characters, those notes are played simultaneously to form a chord.

The range of the music box is a Concert C scale from Middle C (C4) on the left to High C (C6) on the right.

When a chord is played, the sounds of all previous chords are stopped.  If a line does not contain any notes, then the previous chord is sustained at reduced volume.

### Input

Input will be several lines of text.  Your program should read and follow the directions line-by-line.

If a line contains `### lines per minute` then each following line of music should be played at that tempo.  There may be more than one tempo change in the piece, and your program should be able to change tempos.  The tempo change itself does not take up any time.  There will always be a tempo mark before any music lines.

If a line contains music (15 characters long, all characters either `.` or `O`), then those notes should be played and sustained for the correct duration (given by the tempo).

If a line does not fall into either of the above categories (like `Music from...` and `CDEFG...` in the above example), then it should be ignored completely.  The program should act as if they weren't there, simply skip over them with no pause.

### Output

Output could either be sound from the speakers, or a playable .MP3 or .WAV music file.

## QUESTIONS

Should this be code golf?  I assume so, <s>although I want an added bonus for improved sound quality.</s>  It's probably not going to be possible to enforce sound quality requirements.

Are there any other things to add?  Or, is this pretty much ready to go?

Comment: Can we take it that there will always be a tempo change before the first line of music? It's hard to see how you could judge sound quality in an objective way. I like the question though.

Comment: Yes, there will be a tempo change before the first line of music.  Also, I agree that sound quality probably shouldn't be the focus, I have the real software for that.

Comment: What about sharps / flats? Could you clarify the sustain req with respect to the envelope you expect for e.g. note,sus,sus,sus? How much flexibility when note length not a factor of sample rate? (E.g. 57bpm @ 16kHz: if there are 57 lines must output be exactly 60*16000 samples or can each line be rounded to 16842 samples?) If raw output (i.e. wav without RIFF header) is not allowed, best to be explicit.

Comment: "When a chord is played, the sounds of all previous chords are stopped" — this isn't how music boxes normally behave; each note just fades out until it's played again. Also, how about accepting MIDI files?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 12):

## 2048 Low Score

The goal is to make an algorithm that plays as low score in 2048 as possible.

### Rules

- Your AI will play the game of 2048 repeatedly.
- If a game takes more than 2s or scores more than 5000, it will be terminated and score 5000 will be used.
- If a game gets to `Game Over`, the final score will be used.
- The quality of the algorithm will be the average score of the separate games.
- After 4 weeks, the winner will be chosen. However, if another algorithm is proposed, I will test it and change the winner if necessary.

**Choosing the winner**

- Each algorithm will be run 1000 times.
- The best 10 algorithms will be run again 10000 times to precise the quality.
- If the score of the two best algorithms is closer than 3% from each other, they will be run 20000 more times. If they are closer than 3% after this, both will be named as winners.

### Algorithm specification

**C++**

- An example code is in files [2048-core.cpp](https://github.com/tohecz/2048/blob/master/2048-core.inc) and [rand.cpp](https://github.com/tohecz/2048/blob/master/rand.cpp).
- Your code should follow the example of that file: a function `int NextStep(const Game&)` should be provided.

**Other languages**

- I surely work with Python, I should be able to run Java. For other languages, provide a short code together with a way how to compile it, so that I can see what can be done.
- Provide a program code that accepts the following input:

  ```
  <size-of-the-board> <score> <1-if the last performed move actually did something> <the-board-top-line-goes-first>
  ```

  So a typical output line is:

  ```
  4 156 1 0 4 8 2 0 0 0 8 0 0 2 32 0 0 0 4
  ```

  And outputs one number for the next step: `0=UP`, `1=RIGHT`, `2=DOWN`, `3=LEFT`.
- For linking your script to the interpreter:

  1. Download [2048-core.inc](https://github.com/tohecz/2048/blob/master/2048-core.inc), [2048-pipe.sh](https://github.com/tohecz/2048/blob/master/2048-pipe.sh) and [io.cpp](https://github.com/tohecz/2048/blob/master/io.cpp)
  2. Compile `2048-io` by `g++ -O3 -o 2048-io io.cpp`
  3. Run `./2048-pipe.sh ./yourprogram` , this should work well.

**My PC specification**

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 4GB RAM
- Fedora linux 3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64
- gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC)
- (Anyways, I believe that providing 2 seconds per run is more than generous and should be fine. If more people complain they would use more time, I can extend it.)

---

## TO BE SOLVED:

- How to make it available to Windows other than C++?
- Proper tagging.

Comment: Why not keeping the contest open forever? If you close it after some time, that would be annoying for people who see your contest when it is already closed if they want to participate.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Well, I can't guarantee that I will be here forever, and I limit the time of computation to _2s on machine_. But you're right, that's not much a burden, so I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: @tohecz: In a previous contest I wrote a Python wrapper for submissions. This is reasonably cross-platform (using `subprocess` for communication), so I think it could work for your challenge. I could volunteer to write such a thing if your problem was posted.

Comment: As far as tagging goes, I'd go with code-challenge.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 12):

## Meta Code Bots

I'm just giving this a "code bots" title because that's the most similar previous KOTH. This version is based on the [Twin Tin Bots](http://www.flatlinedgames.com/Games/twin_tin_bots) board game, and will probably be given a better name before posting.

On a far away planet, dozens of small mining robots compete for resources in the form of tiny crystals.  Each individual bot is quite simple in its programming: given a series of steps, they can attempt to follow it.  These bots, however, are remotely programmable, as their programming can be slowly edited over time to respond to current conditions.  In this challenge, you will write a program to program these bots.

### The Game Field

The playing field is a toroidal grid, with each cell containing either nothing (`.`), a robot ('>'), a crystal (`=`), or a base ('@').

```
..........
.>..@....^
.=..=.>...
.v.......=
..=@..@..^
.........=
^.<.....>=
=.=.=@....
..@....<.@
....=<^.=.
```

### Robot Programming

Each robot contains a program, which is a series of basic steps that the robot can perform.  The program is always 24 commands long.

- `HALT` (`H`)  - If a robot executes this during its turn, its turn is immediately over.  The entire program is initially filled with `HALT`s.
- `MOVE_FORWARD` (`FORWARD`/`F`) - The robot who executes this command will move forward 1 square if possible, pushing up to one other robot/crystal.
- `TURN_RIGHT` (`RIGHT`/`R`) - The robot will rotate clockwise by 90 degrees.
- `TURN_LEFT` (`LEFT`/`L`) - The robot will rotate counterclockwise by 90 degrees.
- `GRAB` (`G`) - The robot will pick up a crystal if there is one directly in front of it. Also, if there is instead a second bot directly in front, this will steal a crystal from that bot's inventory.
- `DROP` (`D`) - The robot will take a crystal from its inventory and drop it, if possible.  If there is an empty space in front, the crystal would fill that space.  If there is instead a robot in front, then the crystal is added to that bot's inventory.
- `ZAP` (`Z`) - This is an interesting command, and it deviates slightly from the original game. A zap command allows one bot to issue a command to a second bot positioned in front of it.  If bot_X is directly facing bot_Y, and bot_Y is within a distance of two, then bot_X can zap bot_Y.  The very next token in bot_X's program will then be executed by bot_Y instead.

  - `ZAP` commands have a range of 2, meaning that the zap can travel across a single empty square to reach a target which is not immediately adjacent to the zapper.
  - The `ZAP` command can be stacked: `Z,Z,F` causes the bot in front of the bot in front of this bot to move forward.
  - An example: The program `L,F` normally causes the current bot to turn left then move forward. The program `Z,L,F` causes another bot to turn left, and then the current bot to move forward.
- `JUMP` (`J`) - This serves as an unconditional jump in the program, a feature not found in the board game.  This causes the program execution to jump forwards to the location *immediately after the next HALT*.  For example, `F,J,R,H,L` causes the bot to move forward and then turn left.  The `R,H` is skipped over.

  - A program with a `JUMP`ed section acts exactly like a program with that section removed.  So, `F,J,R,H,L` acts exactly like `F,L`, and `Z,J,H,D` acts exactly like `Z,D`.
  - `JUMP` can be used to easily switch between multiple complex behaviors.  For example, `F,F,H,R,R` can easily be edited to form `J,F,F,H,R,R`.

Notes:

- The steps `ZAP,HALT` will not have any effect.  The bot performing the halt wouldn't be the current bot, since the zap causes the halt to be performed by the bot directly in front (if any).  The `HALT` command only has an effect if it is executed by the bot whose turn it currently is.
- The steps `ZAP,ZAP,HALT` *might* have an effect.  If two bots are facing each other, then the HALT would be executed by the original bot, ending the turn. If the bots aren't facing each other, then the HALT would be executed by a third bot (or nobody at all), having no effect.
- In the original game, the zap command allows the zapping player to perform "special action" on his turn that affects the target bot (the player, instead of the bot programming, determines what the zap does).  Here, the action of zaps are determined by the bot program.

### Editing the programming

Each turn, the bot's programming can be altered.  Any number of commands can be removed (shifting the following commands to the left and adding a `HALT` to the end).  Only *one* command, however, can be inserted each turn (shifting the following commands to the right and deleting the last one).

### Game Objective

Your goal is to navigate your bot to pick up crystals and return them to a base (they serve as collection points).  Each crystal you successfully `DROP` off at a base earns you one point.  Each bot can only carry one crystal at a time.  These crystals can be acquired by `GRAB`bing them off the ground or by `GRAB`bing from an opponent bot.

### Execution Order

The players take turns in a cycle.  On your turn, your program will receive the current game map (as an object) and your current bot's program.  Your program can then submit the edited bot-program.  Your bot's  program is then immediately executed, affecting the board before the next player's turn begins.

---

More spec coming later...  The controller is currently under construction.

Comment: So the player who's turn it is controls all of the bots, which all execute the same program? How do the bots interleave their actions and the actions they receive via zapping?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, the player whose turn it is only controls their singular bot, which executes its program during the same turn.  Zapping causes an action to be taken immediately by the zapped robot.  More precisely, zapping doesn't change the order of actions, it simply changes which robot is performing the action.

Comment: Here's for hoping for super long ZAP ZAP chains

Comment: Also, I'd argue for multiple bot control (maybe 5 or so)?  It'd allow for complex shipping operations

Comment: @NathanMerrill There's not really anywhere to ship stuff to at the moment though.  I am undecided about whether I should just have the bots collect crystals (no need to return to base) or require them to return to base (which can make the game more complicated).

Comment: Ah, I guess I assumed bots wanted to return crystals to base.  If there are fewer crystals than bots, then this would become a "steal the flag" sort of game?

Comment: `C`: clone. Creates a bot on the square in front of you that will keep executing your string of commands until the next `H` (halt)

Answer (score 12):

## Prime Spiral

[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

This challenge was inspired by [this question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072308/help-with-a-prime-number-spiral-which-turns-90-degrees-at-each-prime) by [@Karl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/203893/karl)

You might be familiar with the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral). What we're doing here is similar, but a little bit different, given a positive integer `N` we generate an image:

On an empty equally spaced rectangular 2d grid choose an arbitrary point and place a 1 then place a 2 on the grid point to the right of the 1. Then continue as follows:

If you're at number `n<N`:

- If `n` is composite: Go straight in the same direction to place `n+1`
- If `n` is prime: Turn right to place `n+1` (overwrite, if there was another from a previous step)
- Repeat this for `n:=n+1`.

Now consider the grid as a pixel image that is plain white. Then colour each pixel where we placed a number on the corresponding grid point. Then choose a finite rectangle that contains all the coloured pixels, and output it as an image.

#### Examples

For `N=10^5` we get following output ([by](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2072702/109451) [@Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263/wojowu))

[image]

Comment: Had the same idea :p Maybe the challenge would be interesting as well if the task was to actually place the numbers of the grid. This would also be doable in languages that don't allow for graphical output.

Answer (score 12):

## ASCII Line Extender

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

## Introduction

I have an ASCII grid of size 10x10

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

Occasionally, slashes and Xs pop up, but they're too small for me to see!

```
+--------+
|        |
|      X |
|  \     |
|        |
|        |
| /   /  |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

I need a program that can extend them so that I know where they are

```
\----\--//
|\    \//|
| \   /X |
|  \ // \/
|   X/  /\
|  //\ / |
| //  X  |
|//  / \ |
//  /   \|
/--/-----\
```

## Challenge

Your task is to create a function or a program that can take in a String of a grid lines separated by `\n` and outputs grid lines separated by `\n` (optionally including a trailing newline). When there is a `\` or a `/`, your program must add slashes diagonally until you reach both ends so that the slashes look like a line. Whenever two lines intersect, you must replace them with `X`. If given an `X`, you must extend in both diagonal directions. You can assume that no lines have already be extended. and you can assume the border is intact. [Standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) format applies.

## Test cases

These test cases do not contain a trailing newline, due to limitations, however you should add them when testing.

Test for overlap

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|  \     |
|        |
|        |
| /   /  |
|        |
|        |
+--------+

\-------/+
|\     / |
| \   /  |
|  \ /   /
|   X   /|
|  / \ / |
| /   X  |
|/   / \ |
/   /   \|
+--/-----\
```

Test for Xs

```
+--------+
|    X   |
| X      |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|    X   |
|        |
|        |
+--------+

\---X-/--+
\\ / X   |
|\X / \  /
|/\X   \/|
/ /\\  /\|
|/  \\/  \
/    X\  |
|   / \\ |
|  /   \\|
+-/-----\\
```

Test for X and avoiding

```
+--------+
|        |
|   \    |
|        |
|        |
|  /     |
|  /     |
|        |
|        |
+--------+

+-\-----//
|  \   //|
|   \ // |
|    X/  |
|   //\  |
|  //  \ |
| //    \|
|//      \
//       |
/--------+
```

Test for slashes in the same row

```
+--------+
|        |
|   \    |
|        |
|     \  |
|        |
|  /     |
|        |
|X       |
+--------+

+-\------/
|  \    /|
|   \  / |
|    \/  |
|    /\  |
|   /  \ |
|  /    \|
\ /      \
|X       |
/-\------+
```

Test for lots of lines

```
+--------+
|  /     |
|   \  / |
| \      |
|      \ |
|  /     |
|     X  |
|        |
| /      |
+--------+

\-\\/---//
\\ X\  ///
|\X \\///|
|/\\ XX/ /
/  \X/X\/|
|  /XX X\|
| ///\X \\
|/// /\\ \
/// /  \\|
//-/----\\
```

Test for empty grid

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+

+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the shortest number of bytes wins!

Comment: @user202729 Thanks.

Comment: I'll add that in as a link, thanks

Comment: I think something is wrong with the second test case, the arms of one of the `X`s are extended in one direction but not the other. Also, this challenge needs a proper spec, i.e. you should describe exactly how the program should behave, rather than just giving examples.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks

Comment: Suggest testcase `XXXXXXXXXX\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nX________X\nXXXXXXXXXX` (_ for space)

Comment: @tsh Is that an empty grid (because it's of size 10x10) or is it a grid that is bordered by `X`s?

Comment: @NathanWood All borders are filled with `X`. Output should be 10 line of 10 `X`s.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Nhohnhehr](https://github.com/catseye/Nhohnhehr)

Comment: If only this was posted...

Answer (score 12):

## The Ever-Changing Labyrinth (Controller WIP)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

---

#### [Controller](https://beefster09.github.io/everchanging-labyrinth/) • [Source](https://github.com/Beefster09/everchanging-labyrinth) • [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124298/the-ever-changing-labyrinth-discussion) • Submit

This is a 2-player asymmetric KotH challenge.

- One player controls a pair of telepathically connected adventurers who are trying to get through a maze.
- The other player has the ability to change the maze and tries to keep the adventurers from solving it.

### Gameplay

The game is made up of a variable number of rounds, each consisting of up to 1000 turns.

At the beginning of a round, the Maze Master creates an \$n \times n\$ maze, starting at \$n = 3\$, and increasing by \$1\$ on each subsequent round.

Every cell of the maze must always be reachable from every other cell.

Both adventurers begin on the northwest corner cell. The goal is on the southeast corner cell. One adventurer begins facing east and the other begins facing south.

The game proceeds in a turn-based fashion, alternating between each player.

- Adventurers:

  - Observe surroundings of themself and the other adventurer:

    - The wall directly ahead on the current cell is observed
    - If there is no wall directly ahead on the current cell, every wall is observed along each cell ahead in a straight line until a wall obstructs the adventurer's sight
    - The walls on the left and right of the current cell are observed
    - If there is no wall to the left, the wall ahead on the cell to the left can be observed
    - If there is no wall to the right, the wall ahead on the cell to the right can be observed
    - The relative position of the other adventurer, if present on one of the cells they can see.
  - Either moves forward, changes orientation, or waits
- The maze master, in order:

  - Receives \$ 1 + \lfloor \log_n(t) \rfloor \$ mana (where \$t\$ is the turn number, starting at 1), which can be used to modify the maze
  - Observes the entire maze, including the position and orientation of each adventurer
  - May remove a wall from anywhere in the maze that is not currently visible to either adventurer
  - May add a wall to anywhere in the maze that is not currently visible to either adventurer, provided it does not separate the maze into two unconnected halves.

Illustration of how adventurers observe the maze:

[image: Adventurer vision 1]
[image: Adventurer vision 2]

The adventurer in the above image is facing east and sees all the green cells and walls. The dotted green lines indicate non-walls the adventurer can see.

Adventurers may occupy the same space and face different directions. Observation occurs before either of them chooses an action; movement is resolved simultaneously.

The cost to modify the maze increases according to the fibonacci sequence. The first time a particular wall segment is added or removed, it costs 1 mana, the second time costs 1 mana, then 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55... Modification cost is independent for each edge of the grid where a wall segment can be placed, so it is more costly to toggle the same wall than it is to toggle different walls each time.

The maze master can stockpile an arbitrarily large amount of mana, but can only change two walls per turn (removing one, then adding one)

The round continues until either of the two adventurers reaches the goal cell, at which point, the game will continue onto the next round.

If neither reaches the goal after 1000 turns, then the maze master wins and the game ends.

The maze master does not carry over mana between rounds.

### Coding

- Both players may retain as much information as they wish for the entire duration of the game. State may carry on from one round to the next.
- State and retained information will not be remembered between games.
- Players will not be able to access the state of the other player.
- Each player will receive an isolated RNG state at the beginning of each game. To ensure that all games have the same outcome with a given seed, all non-deterministic behavior *must* use the provided RNG. (Math.random is overridden for each bot, just in case)
- Each bot is allotted 50ms of CPU time at the beginning of the round and 1ms for each turn. Exceeding this allotment will result in a strike.
- Maze generation has a time limit of \$n^2\$ ms. (i.e. 9ms for the \$3 \times 3\$ maze, 16ms for the \$4 \times 4\$ maze, 25ms for \$5 \times 5\$, and so forth.)
- Adventurers are given 10ms to set up state between rounds. Exceeding this time limit results in a strike.
- Generating an illegal maze will result in a strike.
- If a wall added to the maze divides the maze into two unconnected halves, the maze master will receive a strike.
- If a wall to be added or removed is visible by either adventurer, the wall will not change but the mana will still be spent.
- If the maze master does not have enough mana to perform *both* of its requested actions, its actions will be ignored.
- If the maze master specifies the same wall for both removing and adding, the actions will be ignored.
- If the maze master tries to remove a wall that is already missing or add a wall that is already present, the relevant action will be ignored.
- Illegal adventurer moves will be treated the same as a wait action.
- If a bot gets a strike, the game will be thrown out of the tournament as an outlier. If any particular bot gets 3 strikes during the tournament, it will be disqualified, and all the matches it was a part of will be discarded and ignored.
- Submissions may not attempt to exploit bugs in the controller in order to break other rules.
- Submissions must be compatible with being run inside web workers as well as being run in the foreground.
- Submissions may not call any asynchronous functions (usually I/O)

#### Adventurers Interface

Your submission must define the body of a function which receives a single argument (`random`, a function that returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1) returns an object with the following interface:

```
startRound(mazeSize: number)
takeTurn(vision: [Vision, Vision]) -> [number, number]
```

`takeTurn` should return a pair of integers describing the action taken by each adventurer. Actions are defined as follows:

```
const ACTION = {
    WAIT: 0,
    FORWARD: 1,
    TURN_RIGHT: 2,
    TURN_AROUND: 3,
    TURN_LEFT: 4,
}
```

Vision is defined as an object with this schema

```
{
    ahead: [
        {
            ahead: true | false,
            left: true | false,
            right: true | false,
        }
        ...
    ],
    leftAhead:  true | false | null,
    rightAhead: true | false | null,
    friend: [number, number] | null
}
```

The zeroth element of the `ahead` array represents the *current* cell the adventurer is on, and each subsequent element represents the next cell ahead.

`null` means that wall cannot be seen, so it is uncertain whether it is present or not.

`friend` will be an ordered pair of numbers representing the number of cells ahead and the number of cells to the right (will be -1 when the other adventurer is to the left) that the other adventurer is relative to this one. If the other adventurer is not visible, `friend` will be `null`

#### Maze Master Interface

Your submission must define the body of a function which receives a single argument (`random`, a function that returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1) returns an object with the following interface:

```
generateMaze(mazeSize: number) -> Maze
takeTurn(mana: number, maze: Maze) -> [WallCoord | null, WallCoord | null]
```

`generateMaze` should return a row-major array of arrays of objects that describe the east and south walls of the cell. Each cell must have the following schema:

```
{
    east: boolean | null // will be null along the east edge of the maze
    south: boolean | null // will be null along the south edge of the maze
}
```

`takeTurn` should return a pair of wall coordinates, describing the wall to remove and the wall to add. Both coordinates are optional and may be null or undefined. Wall coordinates should be an array of the row, column, and `'south'` or `'east'` representing the location of the wall. The schema is as follows:

```
[number, number, 'south'|'east']
```

The maze provided to `takeTurn` is similar to the maze expected to be returned by `generateMaze`, but with two additional properties on each cell to define the mana cost to update:

```
{
    eastCost: number
    southCost: number
}
```

### Submission Format

In order to aid answer scraping, please format your submissions in the following format:

```
# <submission type>: <name>

Optional blurb

    // relevant functions, constants, variables go here

    return /* the object */

Description/explanation of how the bot works + whatever you want
```

`<submission type>` must be the exact string of either `Adventurers` or `Maze Master` which corresponds to your submission type

Only the first code block of your post will be scraped. Submissions will be loaded as if they are the body of a function, which is executed once with no arguments. Submission names should be different from any other submissions.

You may submit both an adventurer bot and a maze master bot, each in its own post. You may also submit multiple bots of the same type as long as they are reasonably different from each other. Please don't hog the leaderboard with near-identical bots.

### Scoring and The Tournament

Adventurers compete only with other adventurers, and the same goes for maze masters.

The overall score for a game for both roles is 1000 points per maze completed by the adventurers minus the number of turns taken in total. Score can go negative.

Each adventurer bot will play against each opposing maze master bot an equal number of times until the ranking of the top 5 bots for each role are established with 95% confidence. The overall tournament score for a given bot is averaged across all games that bot played in the tournament.

The adventurer bot with the highest score wins.

The maze master bot with the lowest score wins.

Scores will be updated when a adventurer or maze master is added or updated.

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Pull requests welcome on the controller. Vanilla JS only (Current ES standard is fine), preferably, though jQuery is probably ok. It needs to work on GitHub pages in Firefox and Chrome without needing babel or webpack or similar.

Parts still in need of implementation:

- Fix bugs in Maze Master modification handling (there are certain cases where visibility is not respected properly)
- Code scraper
- Tournament controller
- Better syntax error reporting for bots
- Foreground error reporting for bots (instead of tucking it away in dev tools)
- (nice-to-have, preferably before posting to main) improved renderer that shows visible cells and walls and the effects of the last move (or better yet, changes since last render).
- (nice-to-have, can wait until after posting to main) background game runner that runs in a web worker and can be controlled by the tournament controller

I recommend checking in via the chat room to avoid duplicating work.

Beta bot submissions also welcome, though I'm not sure how these are going to be integrated at the moment.

Comment: Assumes that the maze master will only wait if the adventurer waits, would that always make waiting a bad choice for the adventurer?

Comment: Does "not visible" mean "not visible at the moment"?

Comment: Is the "increase over time" by power of 2 or linear?

Comment: @user202729 waiting is probably never a good idea for the adventurer, yes, and linear.

Comment: Would the score of every maze master change whenever an adventurer program is posted, and vice versa?

Comment: Perhaps "if the game doesn't terminate after X turns then the score will be X", with X large enough such that the optimal adventurer can always achieve a score smaller than X (but small enough so it's practical to compute)

Comment: Regarding language: if the challenger is implemented in some language that can invoke other programs (such as JavaScript (Node.js)), then it's possible to communicate over standard input/output and let people submit in any language.

Comment: There should be some time limit for each turn.

Comment: @user202729 A couple reasons why I probably won't communicate over stdin/stdout: 1. it can be tricky to avoid deadlock; 2. I want the challenge to be accessible to many users without requiring them to download additional language runtimes.

Comment: So the observed information would be [number of free cells to the left, number of free cells to the right, number of free cells in front]?

Comment: "The behavior must be deterministic with a fixed RNG"? (I'm not sure how to phrase this.)

Comment: There exists a maze master algorithm that makes the duration O(n^4) moves regardless of the adventurer algorithm, where n is the side length.

Comment: And I believe that asymptotically it's not possible to do better.

Comment: So the judge program is written in browser JavaScript?

Comment: More information: the maze algorithm is to make two long passage from the start to the end, at all point in time at least one of those is open, whenever the adventurer gets close to one end then open the other end and close that end. It can be calculated that the passage length is O(n^2), and the maze master has O(n^2) walls to block/unblock for each round, so the number of rounds is O(n^6) (not n^4). I think the constant factors is pretty small, about 1/2 or 1/4.

Comment: Given that this is all in the same process, reducing the time limit to something like 1ms would be okay (JavaScript is not very slow)

Comment: @user202729 Are you factoring in the increasing cost to change walls? Since you have to change different walls each time to maximize mana efficiency, that *should* drop the degree of round length by a factor of n.

Comment: After n^4 rounds, the maze master receives n^6 (mana), and need to change n^4 walls. At each end there are n^2 different walls to change. Changing each one n^2 times takes n^4, so the total is n^6. Just enough.

Comment: The maze master receives \$n^4\$ mana in \$n^4\$ rounds. One mana per round.

Comment: by round, I mean each time the adventurer moves around the maze (and a wall need to be changed)

Comment: The "long corridor" has a small branching factor.

Comment: For maximal distance, that might work, but if set to too small the adventurer might be able to immediately see the exit; while if it's too large then the maze master would have enough time to modify the maze to the "long corridor" one.

Comment: Mirror and camera might work, but if the adventurer have too many of them they might be able to solve the maze in linear time (by placing mirrors/cameras such that they can see all the parts they have walked through, so it's like a normal path-finding).

Comment: Here are a couple more ideas that buff the adventurer: a) randomly generated initial maze (might make the game too stale), b) mana costs are `2 ** n` instead of `n + 1` (personal favorite), c) *2 adventurers,* and only 1 has to reach the exit, d) adventurer can move *perpendicular* to the direction they're facing, e) adventurer can move *any* number of cells forward in a turn. I don't know how any of these affect the problem, though, as I haven't yet had time to sit down and analyze it.

Comment: @Alion I took your exponential mana cost suggestion as well as the dual adventurers. The dual adventurer idea is brilliant, as it makes the adventurer far more interesting without adding an additional action type.

Comment: One idea - make the maze master get 1 + (turns // 100) mana per turn, to make it harder to just wait out the maze master

Comment: @StackMeter I'd prefer to make that a logarithmic increase, but I like the idea generally.

Comment: @Beefster maybe 1 + log2(turns)? Feel free to change that at your discretion.

Comment: I can help with the controller.

Comment: @Ausername I may take you up on that. I have created a github repo for it already, but haven't pushed my latest changes. I will be posting a link later tonight and welcome pull requests. I could definitely use help on tournament implementation, naturally after the skeleton of the controller is nailed down.

Comment: @Beefster Ok. What language?

Comment: @Ausername Javascript

Comment: @Beefster Good - I'm mediocre at Python, but actually quite good at JS.

Comment: @Ausername Some help on prettying up things would be appreciated. I haven't bothered with any css yet. And I think this is my cue to create a chat room.

Answer (score 11):

## Thinking functionally (1): removing variables

*If you're not programming functionally, then you're programming
dysfunctionally.*

Long time ago, in the first ages of universe, coders and variables were living peacefully; but one day, they turned evil and then began a long war between them and men. Unfortunately men could not do much against so many variables. Only a few men are still alive today, but fortunately you can do something for them. You have heard about the ancient art of computer programming and you even spoke one day to a very old functional programmer. Your mission is to kill as many variables as you can.

*This should be the first challenge in a longer series called "Thinking functionally"*.

**Goal:** write a short and interesting piece of code in some language where variables are usually needed (we all know that you can write some code in J or in some stack-based language with no variable, but please, choose some other language for this challenge), and use fewer variables than what would have been expected. You must explain what you did.

**Rules:** What has to be avoided here are mainly variables involved in keeping some information for later use (next step, next iteration, next line, etc.); this covers global or local variables, closures, etc.; if list or tuples are obviously used to replace several variables with no interesting "trick" they should be avoided. Using complex numbers in a tricky way is ok, but using some mathematical operation with them should be preferred rather than merely using separately both parts in the number. Using bitwise trick is fine, but again, try to be clever (see example 1 below) and don't use them only with some masks for separating the data. In all cases, mathematical tricks should be preferred rather than complicated ways of inserting data in some type. On the other hand, you are allowed to use as many bound variables for writing functions as required. Your code should explicitely contain an interesting "trick" for avoiding a variable in a place where everybody else would have used one.
*The most important requirement is: don't try to hide data with too much energy, rather ask yourself if data is really useful.*

**Example 1:** Here is a first example in python, acceptable and interesting. The computer will guess which number you are thinking at with an optimal strategy, with only one variable.

```
a = 256

while True:
  print("I am going to guess the number you are thinking at.")
  print("Is it",a,"?")
  print(":: 0 for less, 1 for more, Ctrl-C for OK")
  a = (
    [
      lambda x: x - ( (1 + (x ^(x-1))) >> 2 ),
      lambda x: x + ( (1 + (x ^(x-1))) >> 2 )
    ]
  )[input("? ")](a)
```

*Explanation:* usually this game requires at least two variables, a and b, which allow the program to remember the smallest and largest possible number, then a third number is computed (a+b)/2 and a or b is updated according to the answer of the player. Here the code uses only one variable, and checks for successive bits in order to set them or not. It is obvious here that no hidden data is used, but we notice that the "natural" way of coding this game is redundant; using two variables isn't really needed since each guess actually belongs to a single possible path.

**Example 2:** Here is another example, acceptable but not as much interesting. How can I swap two variables?

```
a = 42
b = 17
a = a + b
b = a - b
a = a - b
```

*Explanation:* everyone knows that three variables are needed for swapping two variables, and we laugh when students try something like a=b followed with b=a, but you actually can swap variables without any temporary variable.

**Score:** this is a popularity contest; the winner will be for the answer with the most upvotes. Vote for an answer if you find it clever and tricky.

Comment: You probably need to say something about scope (to rule out the argument that the first example actually has three variables: `a`, `x`, and the other `x`) and bit packing (since Minsky proved that it's possible to have a Turing-complete system with only two variables using Gödel numbering, and it can be argued that every Fractran program uses only one variable).

Comment: @Peter Taylor. Thank you for your comment. I do it for the `x` in lambda functions. For the second remark, it is also true, but since it is a popularity contest and since creativity is encouraged, is it absolutely necessary to be too precise regarding how the data has to be stored?

Comment: Popularity contests should be *more* tightly specified than contests with objective criteria, not less, because otherwise they're just an invitation to throw crap at the wall and see what sticks.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. OK. What do you think of the current version?

Comment: The more I think about this question, the less suited I think it is for this site.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. OK. I will try to find another one later. Regards.

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to vote to delete this.

Answer (score 11):

## Evolution of Squares!

This is an idea for a question, and is very much unfinished. Please help me develop it further.

**This is inspired by an evolution simulation I coded a few years ago in JavaScript. The source code and documentation can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/professorfish/pixel-evolution), and you can play the simulation itself [here](http://professorfish.github.io/pixel-evolution/).**

This will be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). I'll provide a specification which all answers must keep to and a few ideas for features, but otherwise add as many features as you can.

### Summary

Your task is to build a simulation which demonstrates evolution by natural selection ("survival of the fittest"). The world in which this will be carried out will be a two-dimensional, *n* by *n* (exact dimensions to be decided) grid. Each cell on the grid can be empty or occupied by a living cell (or by food resources?).

### Cell lifetime

Cells have a 'lifetime counter', which starts at some value when the cell is born and diminishes randomly over cycles of the simulation, so the cells age. It can be replenished by food, but when it reaches 0, the cell dies and is removed (or converted to a food block).

Cells instantly die when completely surrounded? Is that a good idea?

### Genetics

Every so often, cells replicate - produce a copy of themselves, with the lifetime counter reset to maximum, normally with identical characteristics.

There is a probability *p* (to be decided) that when a cell is replicating, its genome will be changed. It can "improve" or get "worse" with equal probability.

The genome can be as simple as an array of true/false booleans for different characteristics, or an array of integers/decimals describing how much of a characteristic there is (e.g. replication per 100 ticks).

Characteristics which could be included are:

- faster replication
- eating other cells to increase lifetime counter
- movement

### The Simulation

The simulation starts with a single, very basic cell, with no fancy characteristics, placed at the centre of the grid. If we decide to implement food resources for cells to pick up, some of these will spawn as well.

Every cycle, cells replicate, age, and die as described above.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea in general. In fact, "challenge using genetic algorithms" is on my PPCG ideas list. :D ... What's not clear to me is if you will prescribe the design of the genome in the final challenge, or whether designing the genome is something participants should do as they see fit. And I think in any case you should define the genome of the cells *before* explaining how the simulation is carried out.

Comment: @m.buettner the reason why I posted this in the sandbox is to get suggestions for it. i still haven't decided whether it will be a [tag:code-golf] with bonuses or a [tag:popularity-contest]

Comment: Do the cells have input? That is, is their behaviour affected by awareness of their remaining lifetime counter (or that of their neighbours), the contents of surrounding grid squares, their location on the grid, the location of nearby or distant food sources? Do they have senses or just follow their genome regardless of their surroundings?

Comment: @githubphagocyte They can have senses. The point of my posting this here is to get ideas for features, either to make a strict specification or just for ideas. I think I'll be making this a popularity-contest

The grid shouldn't wrap at the edges, although in my JavaScript version it sort-of does (the squares are numbered left to right, top to bottom, so you can cross the left edge and end up 1 square above and on the other side from your original position)

Comment: Yes I understood that you are looking for ideas - so I've just thrown those I can think of to see which ones you like. I like the idea of a popularity contest so we can see lots of different approaches. How flexible would you like it to be? You have "squares" in your title - are you attached to this? Would you welcome hexagonal grids too?

Comment: @githubphagocyte If someone can do it, great! Cubes as well, maybe... (+10000 for four dimensions ;) you could display cross-sections of it) What would a good name be then? Evolution of ...?

Comment: I guess the name would be the last thing to settle on, once you know what the possibilities will be. It might be named something to do with cells if you know the cells will always be individual, or something more expansive if creatures can evolve that are made up of more than one cell (like snakes or jellyfish or plants...). Once you decide where to draw the lines the name should follow...

Comment: @githubphagocyte if someone could implement simple multi-celled creatures, that would be amazng

Comment: Another characteristic you could add is immunity to being eaten.  Maybe a cell can only eat those with a higher eating characteristic or those with a life higher than X?

Also, I think that the food is a good idea, but how would the simulation handle finite food?

Comment: There are a wide variety of examples of artificial life out there. Since it's a popularity contest I think there will naturally be variety in the answers. The main thing is to specify the restrictions if you don't want it __too__ open ended... Presumably the length of the code will be restricted as it has to be posted into the limits of a single answer?

Comment: How important is the grid to you? Would you want to exclude grid free artificial life environments where movement is not restricted to integer steps? For example, like in the [Hunger Gaming](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25838/hunger-gaming-eat-or-die) question (it has a video).

Comment: It's possible to get interesting behaviour emerging without even having senses, with a very simple simulation. For example: [this flash version of simulated evolution](http://www.masterbaboon.com/2009/02/simulated-evolution/)

Comment: @professorfish "Evolution of Regular Geometries"?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 11):

## [Construct this point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268947/66833)

Answer (score 10):

## Gerrymander a Map

Congratulations! You have been selected as the chairman of your state's redistricting commission.  It is your job to propose a division of the state into electoral districts.  Your true goal, however, is to make sure that your party wins.  To avoid suspicion, your divisions should appear as innocuous as possible while still giving your party an edge.

The map will be provided as a grid of `0`s and `1`s.  The `1`s represent your party.  Below is a simple example map:

```
0000
0011
1111
```

You are also given a number which represents the number of electoral districts that must be created.  Continuing with the example, `4` will be the number for now.

A **division** of the map is a partition into N number of contiguous regions.  If `P` is the total population (number of digits), each district must contain at least `floor(P/N)` people (digits).  A division can be represented by a new map, with each district labeled by a unique (non-whitespace, printable) ASCII character.  The following represents a division into four segments:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

A map has been **successfully gerrymandered** if the number of districts with a `1` majority is greater than the number of districts with a `0` majority.  In the above division, districts `a` and `b` have a `0` majority, while districts `c` and `d` have a `1` majority.

Here is an alternative division in which gerrymandering was successful.

```
aacd
abcd
bbcd
```

District `a` has a `0` majority, while districts `b`, `c`, and `d` have a `1` majority.  This means that the `1` party has a clear majority in the election.

### The Distortion Metric

There are many ways to gerrymander a map, but you want to make sure that your method passes a visual inspection.  Thus, the shapes should appear as regular as possible.  One method for measuring this is by summing up the perimeters of each district.  The lower the total perimeter, the more disguised the gerrymandering.

```
aa  c
a   c d
  b c d
 bb   d
```

Both divisions above have a total perimeter of 32 (each district has a perimeter of 8).  On a 3x4 map, this is as good as you can get.  Below is a map with a total perimeter of 16 + 22 + 20 + 16 + 22 = 96.

```
abbbb
aaaab
aaaab
acccb
ccbbb
ccddd
ecccd
eeeed
eeeed
edddd
```

### The Goal

The goal is to write the shortest program which, hen given a map of `0`s and `1` and a number N, outputs a gerrymandered division of the map into N districts with the lowest possible total perimeter.

More detail coming soon

Comment: would this be code-golf?

Comment: Do you ever plan to post this?

Answer (score 10):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

## Snakes on a Torus

This would be representative of the classic [Snake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29) video game, but multiplayer. The game would be 2-4 players.

#### Game Description:

Each of the 2-4 snakes will always start at one of four fixed position on the board. Each snake continuously moves forwards at a constant rate. A snake stops moving upon death. The board wraps in both directions, but would be graphically represented as a grid (plane) in an actual game with people, so think of it as "snakes on a plane" if you wish. The dimensions of the grid are TBD.

Apples and poison apples (referred to as Blues and Reds) will spawn in random locations on the board, either at a random rate, or only to replace one as it's consumed (TBD). An blue increases your snake's length by 3. A red reduces your snake's length by 2 (to a minimum of 2). Both are useful in managing your snake's length.

A snake's length will increase by n by the tail not moving for n turns. A snake's length will decrease by n by the tail moving an extra space for n turns. Eating one blue followed immediately by one red should hold the tail for 1 turn, then continue as normal (they cancel).

Your snake will die if its head collides with its body or the head or body of another snake, whether alive or dead. So a head-on collision means both snakes die.

#### Your Bot's Job:

You will create a bot to play this game by submitting which of the 3 directions to move (turn left, straight, turn right) based on information including:

- The game's grid as a 2D array
- Each snake's current length
- An ordered list of your snake's tiles and orientation
- An ordered list of each enemy snake's tiles and orientation, and whether the snake is dead or alive.
- The location of every apple on the board
- The location of every poison apple on the board
- Each player's numbers of wins, kills, and deaths.

You will likely be creating class that is an instance of a base class `Snake`, and implementing the necessary methods. If a move is not returned in the appropriate time-frame, your snake will move straight.

#### The Winner:

Each snake will be pitted against each other snake multiple times. The one which has the highest score after the most games wins. Scoring TBD, but will likely be something like +100 per win, +10 per death on your snake (someone ran into you), -10 per death. Tied games will be possible, since there will be allowed a short period of time while the last snake is alone on the map, in case it would die soon after winning.

#### Suggestions?

**Suggestions for scoring are welcome**. Besides winning, how should apples/length/kills be factored in? Personally, I was thinking most wins, followed by most kills, but I can see that might encourage some people to stay small and avoid everything. Some options (feel free to suggest more):

- Prioritize wins, then kills
- Weighted or point-based scoring for wins, kills, apples
- Just score by length at end of match (so maybe after eliminating the others you could just grow until your bot dies)
- Collect points by being the longest snake every tick

<s>I don't know how soon I will get to making a controller, etc, but let me know what you think. If enough people are interested, I could invest time in it.</s>

[**Controller in progress!**](http://ideone.com/QsVAvw)

Bots must inherit the `Player` class, implementing the `choose_direction()` function.

I'm considering making it so that each snake must pick the next three moves at the same time. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but this would make it more like playing like a person, where you can't always react in time. This would keep the games from going super long if no snake would otherwise run into another one. It would also allow for shenanigans, like zipping in front of another snake to kill it.

Another cool idea would be to have the bots make choices asynchronously as the game progresses, the same way human players do. If you don't choose a direction during a tick, you go straight. This way, you could also take extra time to calculate a move by choosing to return a move less often.

<s>Suggestions for input format would be great. (2D matrix of integer types, multiple lists, etc)?</s>

*This is based directly off of a game I've played, which I think is called either "Worm ed 2" (as in Worm: edition 2) or "Wormed 2". I was unable to find the game in a short search. The game is likely old, and I don't know where it could be found online if at all. If anyone knows of it, please comment!*

Comment: I like the idea of players receiving several input types, so they can choose which to use, or use different types at different times, or mix them, as suits them best. For example, a list of every cell in the arena, and a list of every deadly cell (bodies of yourself and others) and separate lists of the individual snakes bodies, and apples and poison apples.

Comment: What happens in a head-on collision?

Comment: Also, it might be an idea to let apples have an influence on score, to encourage longer snakes. (I realise there is already an incentive to become long, because other snakes are more likely to die by hitting you. This will be stronger when there are more than 2 players. But it's hard to say whether that advantage is strong enough to outweigh the advantage of being small so that you can avoid things more easily, or of just ignoring apples entirely.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Both snakes die in a head-on collision. Also, I am pretty sure I have a TODO comment in the controller for scoring apples. I just haven't figured out what sort of weights to give them. I'll edit into the post that scoring suggestions would be helpful. Perhaps length could be scored? Idk, that's probably something to experiment with after the controller is finished.

Comment: The controller seems to be almost finished other than testing and scoring. I may need to look at timing as well. And if someone can look at improving performance, that'd be great, because [fastest-code] doesn't come naturally to me. There's probably a bunch of duplicated data that could maybe be reused.

Comment: Ah sorry, I saw "Scoring TBD, but will likely be something like +100 per win, +10 per death on your snake (someone ran into you), -10 per death" but had missed the other part where it mentions apples.

Comment: Am I the only one who is amused by the snake game being implemented in Python?... And for something more on topic, is there any particular reason you chose +3 and -2 for blues and reds, respectively? I think +1 and -1 might be appropriate.

Comment: @Beefster Because that's how it was in the original game. It would take much longer to play if they were +1/-1. And their value difference is 1 (3 - |-2|) so all lengths are still possible. This makes it so that red apples are actually sometimes useful in practice, because if you get a few too many blues, you may want to shrink yourself. They are not there to simply be avoided.

Answer (score 10):

## N-Player Battleship

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### The Rules

- The field is a 5N by 5N grid, where N is the number of players.
- The controller places each player's ships randomly.
- Each player can see their ships and the shots they have made, successful or not. Each player can also see other players' *successful* shots.
- Each player gets one shot per turn.
- Each player's fleet consists of, for a total of 21 squares altogether

  - 1 aircraft carrier - 5 squares
  - 1 battleship - 4 squares
  - 2 destroyers - 3 squares
  - 3 assault boats - 2 squares
- You are allowed to keep state information between turns, but not between rounds/games.

### The Specs

#### Input

Input will consist of one integer and a list of lists, space-separated, like so: `3 [[S, X, .],[S, O, M],[S, ., H]]`. This corresponds to the following grid:

```
S X .
S O M
S . H
```

These are the meanings of the characters:

- `.` Unknown (i.e., it's empty or no one has attacked there yet)
- `O` A piece of your ship that has not been hit
- `X` A piece of your ship that has been hit
- `M` One of your missed attacks
- `H` A hit from another player
- `S` A ship that has been sunk, either yours or an enemy's

#### Output

Output must be a pair of integers in the format `x y`.

### Meta

- Adjustments to the fleet?
- More details needed in the spec or rules?

Comment: There would be more opportunities for interesting strategic decisions if you knew *which* enemy had been hit on each square.

Comment: If we assume that because this is KOTH, all 5 bots are competing in real-time on a host machine, then don't you need to standardise on a language (or at least open-source the code for the arena in the language(s) accepted) so people can write compatible bots?

Comment: @sysreq: My plan is to communicate via STDIN/STDOUT, and bots will not communicate with each other, only with the controller.

Comment: I've never played battleship with more than one other person: suppose my bot guesses `(4, 8)`. Is it a hit if *any* of the other bots have a ship in that spot?

Comment: what if more than one bot does; all bots stay completely anonymous though the entirety of the game?

Comment: @sysreq: I think it'll be better to have only one bot's ship per square. Yes, a hit will be a hit if any bot has a ship that occupies that square.

Comment: Will you be willing to open source the controller code (even if this challenge never goes up)? in the interests of fairness, of course, and that aside this is such a cool idea and I want to be able to do it myself (with less work and someone else's better code)

Comment: is the input in the form of command line args or `stdin`?

Comment: @sysreq: Ah, whoops. Input will be as command line args, most likely, At least, initially. I don't know exactly how it'll work yet. And yes, of course I'll open-source any code I write for this.

Comment: Depending on your implementation of the controller (and some clever code) it might be possible to write your controller's `stdout` to a `named pipe` and then require our bots to read `stdin` from said pipe --- almost like letting your controller write to the bots' `stdin`.

Comment: are non-fatal hits to other player's ships represented like `S`?

Comment: Also, the field you use for the example is a bit small; I think you should use a 10x10 (2 players) example

Comment: I think that known-empty spots and unknown territory should be represented differently (i.e., known-to-be-empty spots as `_` and unknown as `.`)

Comment: @sysreq: Known-to-be-empty spots are misses, `M`. Non-fatal hits to other ships are just hits, `H`. Yes, the example field is small. I wrote this post at like 3 in the morning and it was big enough to have each kind of character... :P

Comment: Ah, those were stupid questions but thanks anyways.

Comment: Ships will *only* ever be horizontal and vertical, yes?

Comment: @sysreq: That is correct.

Comment: I can't wait for this challenge to go up so I can post my programs!

Comment: @sysreq: Oh, goodness...I *actually* have to do this? Bah. :P ;)

Comment: Well, now that I've written [a fairly good bot](http://pastebin.com/BxpdCa33) I should hope you do (or at least allow me to write a controller, if you're lazy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32539/discussion-between-elendia-starman-and-sysreq).

Comment: @El'endiaStarman are you there? Your profile says you were online recenty.

Comment: Is it the case that no two ships may be touching each other? ( I think this is a rule in normal battleship.)

Comment: @ICanHazHats: That is correct. The controller will be handling ship placement.

Answer (score 10):

## [Validate Sudoku on a Mobius Strip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235767/validate-sudoku-on-a-mobius-strip)

Comment: I think loosening the input and output requirements would be well received.

Comment: @pajonk can you give an example?

Comment: Like inputting in any consistent format (including comma separated, native types of arrays etc., in reverse order, rows/columns first, ...). And the same for output.

Comment: @pajonk, so basically saying your input and output can meet your needs so long as you accept all of the squares as input and output all of the squares as solved (paraphrasing of course)?

Comment: Well, hmmm, yes.

Comment: @pajonk how's that?

Comment: Looks good now (for me).

Comment: I like the puzzle idea, I think it's neat. However I feel like as a code-golf challenge this just has a lot going on.  Big challenges can be fun but the bulk of this is pretty much the same as the existing solve a sudoku challenge with a different shape.  If you really want to stick with this challenge I can recommend pruning the challenge down a bit, and going with "validate a mobius sudoku instead".  Most solutions to the existing challenge would probably do that as a sub-challenge anyway and it's the most unique part.

Comment: @WheatWizard how's that?

Comment: @WheatWizard do you mind helping me rephrase it? I changed it to accept a completed strip as input and provide whether the provided input is a valid solution as output, but perhaps I'm having trouble with making that a clear statement?

Comment: Oh sorry I interpreted "How's that?" as you not understanding what I was saying.  I've read the changes now and I think it is good.  You might want to check out [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/what-outputs-should-i-allow-for-decision-problems) in terms of output.

Comment: @WheatWizard so like `0` for false, input for true?

Comment: I'm not making any concrete suggestion here, it is up to you. I'm just point out a place where we have had discussions about this so you can read what people have said and come to the conclusion that suits you.

Comment: @WheatWizard I appreciate it; I was pointing out where I arrived for feedback before updating the post lol

Answer (score 10):

## [Don't touch the walls!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248571)

Comment: Explain "non-jagged" a bit more.

Comment: Also, make the 3D test case appear earlier, else it seems like you "added a twist".

Comment: Can multi-dimensional be 1D? 100D? 0D?

Comment: Re: "non-jagged" - I think you may use `"rectangular"` as it will be more intuitive, and explain that in non-2D case all dimensions of the array must have the same length (per analogy to the 2D case).

Comment: Why this "touch the edges" framing, when you can just say something to the effect of "not the first/last item or within the first/last item of the array/a subarray"? I feel like that explanation should come *much* sooner. i.e. before the first example

Comment: not quite a duplicate, but this is the opposite of [hollow out an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71591/hollow-out-an-array)?

Comment: @cjquines It's related, but that only runs in 2 dimensions, and being the opposite way round makes it quite different

Answer (score 9):

### Number-Hopper Maze

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/solving-a-number-hopper-maze

Write a program that solves the Number-Hopper maze described above. The input will be an ASCII art description of the maze

```
+------------+-----+
|x        |18|28  o|
| +--+--+ |  +--+--+
| |13|29|4|27|10|25|
| |  |  +-+--+     |
| |  |       +-----+
| |  |    |      23|
| |  +----+  ------+
| |  |    |        |
| |  | |  +------  |
| |  | |           |
| |  | |  ------+--+
| |  | |        |8 |
| |  | +-----+  |  |
| |  |  22|9 |  |  |
| |  +----+  |  |  |
|       14|11|     |
+---------+--+-----+
```

- `-` and `+` are walls, they are interchangeable
- `x` is the starting point
- `o` (lowercase O) is the destination

The numbers are hop points, to hop from number A to B, you must pay the cost of `abs(A - B)`, the positive difference between two numbers. The goal is to find the solution with the minimum cost.

The solution for the example above is `x-13-11-9-8-29-28-o`, with total cost of 4.

The input of the program will be the ASCII art of the maze, and the output is the sequence of numbers to hop, with the total cost. In the format of `x-13-11-9-8-29-28-o 4`

To qualify, you algorithm must be under or equal to `O(n^2)`. Include an informal proof if others suspect you.

I don't want to see pure brute-force solutions where obvious bad solutions such as moving in loops and making total 99999-steps for a small maze are included in the solution space.

The shortest code wins.

Comment: So the problem is (1) build a undirected, weighted graph from the ASCII maze and (2) find the shortest path from "x" to "o" in that graph. Part 2 is cookbook stuff and languages which have good support for it may have a real advantage, but part one presents some choices. I like it.

Comment: You should drop the complexity test, and worry about brute force. Just give an example big enough that brute force won't work. With this kind of problem, it should easy enough to give such a maze.

Answer (score 9):

## Epic Customizable Tank Battle  (Work-In-Progress)

This is an idea I have been working on in conjuction with users @Trimsty and @githubphagocyte in the chat room.  It is inspired by the flash game "Bubble Tanks" by Armor Games.

This will be a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge.

### Main Idea

The main idea is that a large number of competitors fight each other in a large arena.  Each program is the AI of a different tank.  These tanks are customizable from a list of available parts which can be purchased, so the competitors can choose how to upgrade their tank as the battle progresses and they earn points.

**The Arena:**

The arena may be an almost-infinite plane with a light source near the center.  Tanks can travel far away, but lose energy away from the light.  This is a continuous-space game, so the tanks have locations/directions determined by floating-point numbers.

**The Bots:**

The tanks are basically circles, with the center point of the tank being the location.  There is no collision detection, except that projectiles inside of another tank's radius are considered hits.  The tank's size (radius) will be determined by the different upgrades it has, with larger weapons giving more size.

Bots will also have a health level which reduces upon injury from opponent's weapons.  The health will start at some number, and the bot dies upon the health reaching zero.  As bots kill others and collect points, health can be restored over time.

If a tank goes too long without making progress (collecting points or killing), then it will begin to rust.  Rust will slowly damage the tank and kill it.  Rust can be eliminated by making progress.

Weapons also need time to recharge, and this time is dependent upon rust and other factors.

The tanks are solar-powered.  The farther the tank goes from the light source, the slower it can move, the longer it takes for the weapons to recharge, and the shorter its range-of-visions is.

**Bot vision:**

A tank's vision range will be determined by the light level.  If an object is located in a high-light area, then it can be seen from farther away.  An object in a low-light area can only be seen by nearby observers.  A tank will be able to see things which are closer than the light level in that object's location.  The bot will be able to see other tanks, as well as other features (bullets in-flight, heat-seekers, maybe mines).  The information available about other tanks will be that tank's weapons (maybe).

**Winning criterion:**

Each match will be one single battle-to-the-death involving all of the tanks.  The tanks' scores will be the time until death.

It might be that several matches are held with the winner being the contestant with the highest average (or median?) score.

**Upgrade system:**

Each tank starts with a certain number of *skill points* (4000) and a certain *kill value* (10).  The tank can spend skill points on upgrades to the various weapons.  Once a bot spends points on an upgrade, the transaction cannot be reversed.

When a tank kills another, the victor's own kill value is increase.  The killed bot drops skill points on the area which can be collected by nearby bots.  The kill value of a bot determines (in part) how many skill points will be dropped upon that bot's death.

**Types of weapons:**

- Guns of various ranges, strengths, and reload rates
- Lasers
- Mines (proximity and timed)
- Area-effect (damages nearby bots)
- Heat-seekers (costly and very accurate, but short range and low damage)
- Shields (not a weapon, but a form of protection that comes in different strengths)

**Additional Notes:**

There may be different feature which can be added, such as:
- flashlights which enable bots to see farther in the dark zones.
- self-destruct, which scatters the dropped points across a broader area.
- leech-weapons which steal health
- speed boosts or reductions

**Misc.**

Some sample code provided by trimsty about skill points and kill values:

```
class BotsThingy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bots = []
    def fatalShot(self, firer, victim):
        d = (self.bots[firer].points - self.bots[victim].points) / 15
        if d < 0:
            self.bots[firer].killValue -= d
        else:
            self.dropPointsAt(d + 50 + self.bots[victim].killValue * 5, self.bots[victim].location)

# bot.killValue starts out at 10.
# bot.points can be anything that's above 100-ish, I'd say 4000 is good.
```

Comment: The flashlight option could increase the vision radius of its bearer, but also make the bearer more visible to others.

Comment: This sounds interesting.

Comment: You had me at "lasers."

Answer (score 9):

## Transport Tycoon [control program WIP] [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

**The specification is now complete; the control program will now be written**

[Chatroom for this challenge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16845/discussion-between-githubphagocyte-and-professorfish)

Your task is to create an AI which builds a profitable transport network to carry passengers. In each game, the first entry to have $262,144 or more in cash wins!

Every entry must have a name and version numbering for each time it is altered. You may submit up to 8 entries, but they must not collaborate.

### Control

Each round has four players. Each player has a number from 1 to 4.

A simple map will be randomly generated by the control program for each game. This map will be stored in a file `map.txt` *two directories above* your program (i.e. `../../map.txt`), and updated each game tick. Each player's bank balance (as a number without the $ symbol) will be in `../../account_<PLAYERNUMBER>.txt`. Vehicle data will be in `../../vehicles_<PLAYERNUMBER>.txt`. You may view other player's vehicle and account files.

Your program will be invoked once, at the start of the game. When your program has finished initializing, it must output `READY`. If it takes more than 60 seconds to initialize, it will be terminated and disqualified from that game. It may keep files between rounds (for example, to predict an opponent's strategy after watching them for a few games). Other players may not view these files. The tournament will be re-run and the leaderboard updated every 2 days. Your program may not keep files between tournaments.

The control program will put the text `WAITING-player_number` (e.g. `WAITING-4`) and a newline to your program's standard input when each game tick begins. You will submit actions on standard output, separated by new lines, terminated by `END`. Actions that are invalid for whatever reason will be completely ignored. If your program takes longer than 1 second to output `END`, it will receive `TIMEOUT` on standard input and *no action will be executed for this turn*.

If no winner has been found after 30 minutes, the player with the most money wins.

### Map format

The map will be a two-dimensional ASCII grid where the top is north, the bottom is south, the left is west and the right is east. Example:

```
#/////////
######@@@*
/**@@#####
//@@1#@@@*
/@@##@**/#
~~~+~~~~~|
///#######
```

`#` represents a road. `/` represents empty land. `*` is for difficult terrain (e.g. hills, swamps, whatever) - more on that later. `@` represents a house. `~` is a body of water. `+` is a completed bridge over water. `|` is a partially constructed bridge. The numbers 1 to 4 represent stations belonging to players (e.g.: if you are player 4, your stations will be marked as `4`). 5 to 8 represent 'inactive' stations belonging to players 1 to 4 respectively.

The line endings in the file will be Windows-style CRLF.

The top left corner is `(0,0)`. X is horizontal and Y is vertical.

### Construction

Each tick, a player can perform up to 4 construction actions. These are:

- replace a `/` with a `#` (build a road)
- replace a `*` with a `/` (prepare terrain)
- replace a `#` with an inactive station (build a station)
- replace a `~` with a `|` (start a bridge)
- replace a `|` with a `+` (finish a bridge)
- replace one of your stations with a `#` (demolish a station)

You may not perform more than one action on a tile in one turn (you cannot go from `~` to `|` and to `+` in a single turn).

You cannot demolish roads, bridges, water, houses or other players' stations.

Each action costs $512, and is sent to the control program on standard output in the following format (*B* is for Build):

```
B-X-Y-tile
```

For example, this will build a road at (8,4):

```
B-8-4-#
```

Invalid commands will be ignored.

### Vehicles

Each player can own an unlimited number of vehicles. The basic bus has the following properties:

- carries 32 passengers
- travels 8 tiles per turn
- consumes $8 per tile in running costs

Each vehicle can have up to 4 upgrades out of the following (but no more than 2 of each type):

- +16 capacity (denoted by `C`)
- +4 tiles/tick speed (`S`)
- -$2 running costs (`R`)

At most one vehicle can be bought by each player per turn. The basic bus costs $4096 and each upgrade costs $1024; the maximum possible cost is therefore $8192 (all 4 upgrades). A bus can be sold at any time for half of its purchase price (including upgrades; a bus with 4 upgrades can be bought for $8192 and sold for $4096). At most one vehicle can be sold each turn.

The command for purchasing a vehicle is (*P* is for Purchase):

```
P-id-X-Y-upgrades
```

For example, this will buy a bus with no upgrades, assign it the ID 5, and place it at (7,7):

```
P-5-7-7-
```

The command for selling a vehicle is simply (*V* is for Vend)

```
V-id
```

Vehicles are stored in `vehicles_N.txt` in the following format, separated by newlines:

```
id-X-Y-passengers-upgrades-laststationX-laststationY
```

For example, this bus has ID 4, is at (5,5), contains 15 passengers, has two speed upgrades and one running cost upgrade, and last stopped at (3,4). If the bus has never run `A` before, use the coordinates where it was created for the "last station" coordinates. Update the coordinates every time `A` is run for that bus.

```
4-5-5-15-SSR-3-4
```

Vehicles can travel on roads (`#`), bridges (`+`) and station tiles (`12345678`). In the above example, it is possible to drive from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. However, the two road sections in the map below aren't connected, because they are only diagonally touching. Building a road on one of the `*` would solve this.

```
/////
##*//
/*###
/////
```

Vehicles can only stop to pick up and drop off passengers at stations belonging to their owner - player 3's bus can only stop at a `3` or a `7`, but not at any of `124568#+`.

Your AI has complete control over the movement of its buses. It will submit directions as commands. For example, the following command set will move bus 8 in a circle, then two spaces south, then make it offload 8 passengers, then make it wait for passengers (N, E, S and W are north, east, south and west; *R* is for Remove; *A* is for Acquire):

```
N-8
E-8
S-8
W-8
S-8
S-8
R-8
A-8
```

NB: Waiting at a station with `A` counts towards the limit of tiles that the bus can travel each turn, although it is not moving. While waiting, double running costs are charged. A bus may wait for multiple turns. If a bus moves fewer tiles than it is able to (e.g. can move 8 tiles per turn but chooses to move 5 times), halved running costs are charged for the unused turns.

### Passengers

Each time an `R` command is submitted for a bus that is at a station, the bus loses 8 of its passengers. The diagonal distance (using Pythagoras' theorem) between its current station and the previous one is calculated and rounded down (floored). Each passenger offloaded gives this amount of profits (e.g. if the previous station is 1.4 tiles away, each passenger gives $1; if it is 5.9 tiles away, each passenger gives $5).

Each time an `A` command is submitted for a bus that is at a station, the bus gains passengers. Each house in range of your station provides `1/number_of_active_stations_in_range_of_house` passengers.

If there are three stops, A, B and C, and the bus has a route from A to B and then to C, but only picks up passengers at A, then passengers offloaded at B will pay the price for A to B, and passengers offloaded at C will pay for A to C. However, if any passengers are loaded at B, then *all* of the passengers offloaded at C, even if some of them boarded at A, will pay the fare for B to C.

In the map below, the tiles marked with `@` and `#` are in range (4 tiles or less away), but not the tiles marked with `/`; the bus at 1 will gain 32 passengers because there are 32 houses in range and no other stations.

```
////@////
///@@@///
//@@@@@//
/@@@@@@@/
####1####
/@@@@@@@/
//@@@@@//
///@@@///
////@////
```

### Other

You will be charged $64 per turn for each station, active or not, that you own.

Each turn, active stations have a 1 in 8 chance of becoming inactive. This is reverted when a bus runs `A` at the station.

You will start with $32768.

You may not have a negative quantity of money.

When someone wins, all competing programs will receive `GAMEEND` on standard input. They may no longer submit commands after this happens, but they may read and write from files (to prepare for a subsequent game, for example). After 60 seconds, all competing programs will be killed.

The map will be 256*256 tiles.

### Todo

- Write control program
- Write map generator
- Plan tournament format

Comment: check out http://dinopoloclub.com/minimetro/ for a minimalistic transport network game that might be amenable to computer solution

Comment: If a bus makes a journey from station X to station Y to station Z, and not all of the passengers picked up at X get off at Y, how much will they pay when they get off at Z? Will everyone who gets off at Z be charged as if they had travelled from Y? In order to charge the higher amount for a journey from X to Z, would the bus need to avoid stopping at Y?

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yes, it would need to avoid stopping at Y. I don't think there's a way to fix this without overcomplicating things. Alternatively the `R` command could be changed to drop off all the passengers; this would eliminate the option to only drop off some passengers. (This is what happens in OpenTTD - vehicles always drop off all their passengers at stations AFAIK)

Comment: @githubphagocyte which is better? just leaving it as it is or changing `R`?

Comment: I don't have a preference I just wanted to make sure the behaviour is unambiguous. You can model it in as much or as little detail as you like as long as there are no loopholes or unclear behaviour.

Comment: In real life the number of people who get on a bus depends on its announced destination rather than just its pick up point, but I don't think it's necessary to model that in order to have an interesting competition. There's already the potential for complex interaction between companies that can't prevent other companies from using roads they didn't pay for.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I've added a disambiguation: "If there are three stops, A, B and C, and the bus has a route from A to B and then to C, but only picks up passengers at A, then passengers offloaded at B will pay the price for A to B, and passengers offloaded at C will pay for A to C. However, if any passengers are loaded at B, then *all* of the passengers offloaded at C, even if some of them boarded at A, will pay the fare for B to C."

Comment: It's worth trying to think of winning strategies to see if that highlights any loopholes. The best return seems to be from journeys along a straight line a multiple of 8 squares long (or 12 or 16 squares with an upgraded bus). If there are a number of squares nearby where a rival could benefit from building a station, do you benefit from building stations there just to block? How do the costs compare under your current parameters?

Comment: @githubphagocyte I could partially prevent blocking by not allowing a player to build two of their own stations next to each other (but allow them to build next to a competitor). Would that work?

Comment: I suppose it depends whether the cost of building a number of unused stations just to block one rival station is worth it. As long as building a new station isn't too cheap it should sort itself out. I wasn't suggesting preventing people from blocking, just making sure it is sufficiently expensive that it doesn't happen too easily.

Comment: @githubphagocyte Currently the station costs $512 to build and $64 per turn (inc opponent's turns) to maintain. how much higher should the costs be? $1024 and $64 maybe?

Comment: The current figures may be fine. Just something to bear in mind during testing with example contestants.

Comment: Is any controller up for this?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I'm working on it.... one day I'll finish it

Comment: Why don't you put it on GitHub or something?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury https://github.com/professorfish/ttkoth

Answer (score 9):

## Overhanded (Underhanded) Poker

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[overhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overhanded)[card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

> Also if you make [overhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overhanded) a thing I'll whack everyone involved with a large trout ~ [Doorknob](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22604646#22604646)

You and your poker buddy are bored, and seeking to liven up the usual poker game. Playing one hand just isn't challenging any more, and you're looking to add a bit of depth. So, why not play with two?

#### Overview

This is a round robin tournament of two-player poker. For each round, a player will need to make two hands of five cards each. To do this, each player will be dealt seven cards, with three community cards to fill out the hands. After receiving their seven cards, players will be allowed to exchange any number of them for new cards from the deck *one* time.

Once each player has exchanged cards, they will split the ten cards (7 in hand, 3 community) into two hands, **Over** and **Under**. The object for the Over hand is the highest ranked hand, while the object for Under is lowest.

#### Scoring

In each round, a player will receive one point if:

- Their Over hand is higher than the opponent's Over hand **and**
- Their Under hand is lower than their opponent's Under hand

If one hand wins (Over beats Over or Under loses to Under) and the other ties, you get half a point.

If one player wins one and the other wins the other or both hands tie, no points are awarded.

#### Rules

- Standard poker hand rankings apply (link chart or something here)
- Play fair! (will expand on this with the usual KotH stuff)

#### Controller

WIP

#### Meta

Obviously this needs some more work. Initial thoughts, questions?

Comment: I like this idea a lot (and you getting smacked with a trout is intriguing). One suggestion: it doesn't seem you make a mention of *how many* games each bot will play against each other bot. Since this problem is (presumably) dominated by the RNG gods, deciding how many rounds are necessary to ensure rewarding good programs instead of lucky programs may be tricky. ([Relevant meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/how-should-authors-choose-the-proper-sample-sizes-for-probabilistic-programming))

Comment: That's mainly because I haven't decided yet. I'll try to make it enough, but not too many ;)

Comment: Does the second player know how many cards the first one changed or are the changes simultaneous?

Comment: @randomra I think simultaneous is best here. Otherwise I'll have to alternate turns as P1/P2 due to the advantage.

Answer (score 9):

## I'm always right

Given the following input:

- A number consisting of decimal digits, the `guess`
- A number consisting of decimal digits, the `answer`

You are to output a single natural number, the `base`, such that when you interpret the `guess` as a number in the base `base`, the distance between `guess` and `answer` is smaller than for any other choice of `base`.

To be clear,

- `answer` is interpreted as base 10
- `guess` is interpreted as base `base`
- distance means absolute value
- The `base` must be greater than the largest digit used. I.e. if `6` appears in the `guess`, you cannot output a base smaller than `7` because any base smaller than 7 does not use the symbol `6`.

**Motivation and Example**

Your friend asks you a question like "What's the population of New York City?"

You have no clue, so you make a guess "1,400,000 people", you say.

He says "You're an idiot, the population is 8,550,405. You were so far off."

You then do some quick math in your head and say, "I wasn't that far off, I didn't realize you wanted base 10. I was using base 14. In base 10, I said 9,680,832, which wasn't that bad of a guess"

In this example

```
guess  = 1400000
answer = 8550405
base   = 14
```

**Test cases**

Eventually maybe.

Answer (score 9):



Answer (score 9):

*Edit: Posted.*

---

## [Output this string from the `kolmogorov-complexity` tag info page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245511/111305)

Comment: Perhaps reading from the kolmogorov-complexity tag page would actually be an interesting strategy.

Comment: Instead of discouraging the trivial `print` answers, you could make a community wiki answer listing them in various languages

Comment: @ophact That's a standard loophole though, unless OP specifically allows internet access

Comment: @ophact you know what, on second thought you are right, given that that would generally require a lot of boilerplate to access the plate, and then pull the requisite string out of it, if that can be golfed down to something interesting

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms good thought about the community wiki answer for trival answers, I'll add something about that to the post

Comment: actually upon several hours more thought on the subject @ophact, I am inclined to reverse my decision about allowing internet access to the `kolmogorov-complexity` info page, for two reasons: 1, because I feel it is not entirely in the real spirit of this question, which is to golfily produce a string that looks primarily like the result of a cat walking on your keyboard, and 2, because I also don't think that, with the boilerplate for fetching the page from the internet and parsing it, any solution doing that would be at all competitive.

Answer (score 8):

### King Me - Draughts King of the Hill

Note: I made this CW so someone else can take it over, because I have no desire to make the controller and run the tournament anymore.

[Draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts) (or checkers, as it is known in the United States) is a well-known international game. I was surprised that we have not had a draughts King of the Hill yet, so here's one! In case you're unfamiliar with the rules (or perhaps you need a refresher), here are the rules for [English draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts), the version we will be playing.

Draughts is played on a checkerboard that looks like this:

[image: draughts board]

There are two players, white and red, who sit on the side of the board closest to their pieces' starting position. White moves first. Normal pieces (men) may move forward (from the perspective of the player; towards the other player) one space along diagonals, or jump over diagonally-adjacent pieces that are in front of them to capture them and remove them from the game. Because pieces can only move diagonally, they will always be on the dark squares of the board.

For example, the following move is permitted, and would result in the red piece being captured:

[image: jumping]

Players may jump as many pieces in a row as possible when making their move, which results in all jumped pieces being removed. Normally in draughts, jumping is not optional - if you can jump, you must jump, and you must make the longest jump possible. However, for this game, jumping is optional, and you do not have to make the longest jump possible if you do not wish to.

Additionally, when a man reaches the furthest row (the row closest to their opponent), it is promoted to a "king", which confers the ability to move (and capture) backwards along diagonals.

A game is ended when a player's pieces have all been captured or the player cannot make a valid move. The player who cannot move due to being trapped or having no pieces is the loser. To prevent games from going indefinitely, I am adding the additional condition that, if a capture has not happened in 10 turns (a turn being defined as ending after the red player has made their move), the game is ended and declared a draw.

#### The Tournament

Submissions will be accepted for seven days following the posting of this question. At 11:59 PM UTC on the seventh day, registration will close, and the tournament will be run soon after.

Submissions will compete in a round-robin tournament. 5 points will be awarded for a win, 2 points for a draw, and 0 points for a loss. 10 games will be played per match, for each pair of contestants. The submission with the highest score at the end of the tournament will be declared the winner and chosen as the accepted answer. In the event of a tie, total number of wins will be used to decide the winner.

If a bot makes an invalid move or takes longer than 1 second (judged using Java's `Timer` class), it will be ruled as a forfeit for that game.

To make things simple for me, all submissions must be in Java, and will be classes that inherit from a common `Bot` interface. The `Bot` code and `Controller` class are provided below:

[todo: bot and controller code]

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Comment: Maybe as a note you should put that Draughts (Checkers) has been solved, and is in fact the largest game to ever be solved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game#Solved_games

Comment: @geokavel Good point. Since it has only been weakly solved (meaning perfect play can only prevent a loss, rather than force a win), I'm going to compensate for that by increasing the number of points for a win. That should incentivize players to go for wins, rather than forcing draws.

Comment: I still think that the bot that plays perfectly (no loss) will end up the winner of this KoTH, unless you make the win points really high (like 10), so that 1 win amounts to 5 draws.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I want to incentivize winning, but not to the point where perfect play is disincentivized. The winning bot should be one that uses perfect play to avoid losses, but deviates to try to force wins when it can. Besides, the end-game conditions are different here from the style that was solved, so perfect play may not be so perfect here.

Comment: @Mego: I don't think that is what "weakly solved" means. The game if played perfectly results in a draw. It is weakly solved because some positions were proven suboptimal. As a result traversing those parts of the game tree never happened. A computer cannot play this game perfectly as a human could decide to take a suboptimal path but the computer would have no idea what to do. Strongly solving means (roughly) a computer knows what to do at every point.

Comment: Do you intend to post this at some point? I might be interested to write a challenge and a language-agnostic controller (using STDIO and/or argv for I/O), but apparently you and another user have both created a sandbox post on the same topic.

Comment: @Pietu1998 [I posted this in the Secret Santa's Sandbox post a while back](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8024/45941) - it's fair game for anyone who wants to complete it.

Answer (score 8):

## Array Pattern Matching Language

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

Everyone is (or should be) acquainted with the ways of the regular expression. At its core, a regex is made for matching strings. However, it's just matching something, right? Why not match *arrays*? That would be something!

### Description

Your task now is to design and implement a *new* **numeric** array pattern-matching language. The only requirement is that your created language satisfies the mandatory tasks detailed below. However, this being a popularity contest, you may wish to opt for the bonus tasks and maybe even some competitive golfing value.

To be more precise, your language should be able to take **patterns** and match them against arbitrary arrays of integers. They should minimally be used to determine whether or not an array matches the pattern. This can be done by return a boolean, two different strings, etc.

### Voting

As a voter, you should keep in mind the criteria mentioned, and ask yourselves these questions:

1. Is the language trivial? That is, is there a lot that can be done other than the detailed tasks, or is the language minimally designed for these tasks?
2. Is it well described? Does the author explain the solutions and the concept behind the language?

### Tasks

*(Thanks to Nathan Merrill for a lot of tasks!)* Note that, for each task, the empty array can go in either category, unless otherwise stated.

#### 1. That's odd!

Write a program in your language that will match the input array if all of its members are odd; otherwise, do not match.

```
MATCH
 [1, 3, 5, 11, -1]
 [5, 9, 1023, 3243]

NOT MATCH
 [2, 1, 3, 4]
 [0, 5, 6, 0]
```

#### 2. Increasing in membership

Match an array that has each member more than the previous member.

```
MATCH
 [0,1,2,3]
 [2,5,100,203123]
 [-432,-421,123,322]

NOT MATCH
 [0,0,1,2]
 [-2,3,-3]
 [1,3,2]
```

#### 3. Bodyguards

Match only arrays with a `0` on both sides.

```
MATCH
 [0, 1, 2, 0]
 [0, 5, 0]
 [0, 0]
 [0]

NOT MATCH
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5]
 [99]
```

#### 4. Mountain

Match all arrays of the form `[1, 2, 3, ..., N-2, N-1, N, N-1, N-2, ..., 3, 2, 1]`, for any `N`.

```
MATCH
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 [1, 2, 1]
 [1]

NOT MATCH
 [1, 2, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1]
 [3, 4, 5, 4, 3]
 [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
 [2, 1, 1]
```

#### 5. Shifting, 1 to 5

Match only arrays that consist of the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2` "in order", where the elements can be rotated around the array.

```
MATCH
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

NOT MATCH
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4]
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [2]
 []
```

#### 6. Not in my prime

Match an array if and only if all of it's members are *not* prime.

```
MATCH
 [4, 6, 8, 9, 24]
 [20, 40, 42, 45]
 [1, 10, 100]
 []

NOT MATCH
 [1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 401]
 [2, 3, 4]
 [2, 4, 8]
 [3, 5, 7]
 [2]
```

#### 7. Unique

Match only arrays that contain no duplicates.

```
MATCH
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 [5, 15, 25]
 [21]
 []

NOT MATCH
 [3, 4, 5, 3]
 [10, 11, 10, 13]
 [2, 2]
```

#### 8. Not close

Match only arrays that, for each member `N`, do not also have a member `N+1`.

```
MATCH
 [1, 3, 45, 30]
 [20, 23, 26]
 []

NOT MATCH
 [200, 201, 202]
 [3, 9, 100, 4]
 [2, 4, 5]
 [0, 1]
```

#### 9. Arithmetic Progression

Match only arrays that are arithmetic progressions; i.e. there elements increase by a constant factor. (Singletons may go either way.)

```
MATCH
 [2, 6, 10, 14]
 [5, 10, 15, 20]
 [20, 19, 18]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [5, 6, 7, 8]

NOT MATCH
 [5, 25, 125]
 [2, 6, 5]
```

#### 10. Fibonacci-esque

Match only arrays (of length greater than 2) where each element is the sum of the previous two (not counting the first 2), and match all arrays of length 2.

```
MATCH
 [100, 1, 101, 102, 203, 305, 508, 813]
 [-5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 10, 15, 25, 40]
 [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 3, 5]
 [10, 2]

NOT MATCH
 [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
 [91, 32, 32]
 [5, 5, 5]
 [2]
 []
```

#### 11. Self-descriptive

Match arrays that contain their lengths.

```
MATCH
 [1]
 [12, 2]
 [4, 3, 2]

NOT MATCH
 [0]
 []
 [123, 122, 121]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

#### 12. Palindrome

Match all palindromic arrays. That is, arrays that are the same when reversed.

```
MATCH
 [1]
 []
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
 [-1, -1]

NOT MATCH
 [3, 4, 2, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]
 [1, 11]
```

#### 13. Kth element at most K

(You can use 1-based or 0-based indexing. I will give test cases for 0-based indexing.)

Match all arrays whose Kth element is at most K.

```
MATCH
 [0, 0, 2]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]
 [-4, -1, 0]

NOT MATCH
 [2, 42]
 [-4, -92, 4]
```

#### 14. Twins

Match all arrays of even length whose first half is equal to the second half.

```
MATCH
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
 [4, 4]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]

NOT MATCH
 [4, 9, 9, 4]
 [9, 2, 13, 2, 9]
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

#### 15. A simplified date

Match all 3-element arrays which constitute a valid date. The array will be `[year, month, day]`. That is, `year >= 0`, `1 <= month <= 12`, and `1 <= day <= 31`.

```
MATCH
 [2018, 6, 16]
 [1990, 1, 1]
 [0, 6, 31]
 [3014, 7, 13]
 [1293, 9, 9]
 [12, 12, 12]

NOT MATCH
 [-4, 12, 9]
 [100, 100, 4]
 [1929, 13, 31]
 [4102, 12, 32]
```

Comment: I look forward to the answers for this as I would like to have a generalized regex feature in Pytek. :D

Comment: `[]` is a match for "*all members are odd*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah right, drinker's fallacy.

Comment: Can the input be in unary?

Comment: @Downgoat That would hardly be interesting, I don't see why not, but it'd be hardly useful and largely unable to compensate for negative numbers.

Comment: Some of the tasks seem to use matching in the sense of a regex: the array as a whole either matches or does. Others seem to describe a filter, where the individual elements of the array are matched or not and the matched ones are output. If this is intentional, it would be good to mention it in the Description section.

Comment: I *really* like the concept of this challenge.  However, I'd recommend standardizing your test cases:  1. Make your regex an all/nothing match (as Peter Taylor explained). 2. Ensure that your array only contains integers (no matrices).  Then, adding more test cases would be fantastic.

Comment: Possible test cases:  Match if each `0` has a positive integer on both sides.  Match the array [1,2,3,...N-1, N, N-1, N-2...3,2,1].  Match the array [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2] and [2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] and [3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2] and so on. Match an array with only unique elements.  Match an array that doesn't contain both an N and an N+1.  Match the fibonacci sequence with an arbitrary first two numbers.  Match if all of the numbers aren't prime.

Comment: Some task ideas (although you seem to have quite many already): Palindromic arrays. Even-length arrays whose first half equals second half. Arrays whose **k**th element is at most **k**. Arrays that contain their length as an element.

Comment: @Zgarb on the first half equals second half, do you mean arrays like `[1, 2, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes, exactly.

Comment: It seems all the elements are integers and not floats. If that's the case,, you should say so. I think "Is the language trivial?" would be better stated positively, saying that the language constructs are powerful in general, not just tailored to the examples given.

Comment: It seems to me that such a language already exists--it's called Jelly. ;) (And APL, and J.) Wisecracking aside, there are two serious points I want to make: 1) What do you expect submissions to bring to the table that existing languages don't have? Why design a language for this set of tasks when it's essentially already been done? 2) In any case, you should stipulate in the question that submissions must be *new* languages created specifically for this challenge.

Comment: @DLosc I'm thinking of a regular expression language, so it should be somewhat similar to regex. How might I define that in a strict sense?

Comment: Well, you could read up on [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), but I suspect that isn't what you want, since several of your tasks can't be matched by a regular language. (Unique, self-descriptive, and twins, e.g.) Instead, you may be looking for a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), though that still isn't a really "strict" category and you'd have to further specify what you mean by declarative.

Comment: See also the article on [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching).

Comment: Perhaps a task could be to match arrays with equal consecutive elements (e.g. `[1,2,2,3]` and `[9,9]`, but not `[1,0,2,3]` or `[6,5]`)? That might be too trivial. (I was going to suggest solving [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95409/42545), but the tasks are about *matching* arrays, not *modifying* them.)

Comment: Why is `[5, 6, 7, 8]` not an arithmetic progression?

Comment: @Adám Good question, I'll fix that

Answer (score 8):

### Count the cubes

Here is a picture of a diamond tiling shamelessly stolen from [Random ASCII Art of the Day #5: Diamond Tilings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51222/random-ascii-art-of-the-day-5-diamond-tilings):

[image]

However it also has the property of representing a 3D isometric view of a 5×5×5 cube with 59 cubes removed, leaving 66 behind. (Cubes obscured by other cubes are assumed to exist.)

Your task is, given an ASCII art representation of a diamond tiling, is to output both the number of cubes removed and remaining. For example (some shamelessly stolen from [Scale up a Diamond Tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50562/scale-up-a-diamond-tiling)):

```
  ____
 /   /\
/___/  \ -> 1 0 or 0 1
\   \  /
 \___\/
  ________
 /   /\   \
/___/  \___\ -> 1 1
\   \  /   /
 \___\/___/
  ____________
 /   /\   \   \
/___/  \___\___\ -> 2 1 or 1 2
\   \  /   /   /
 \___\/___/___/
  ________________
 /   /\   \   \   \
/___/  \___\___\___\ -> 3 1 or 1 3
\   \  /   /   /   /
 \___\/___/___/___/
  ________
 /\   \   \
/  \___\___\
\  /   /\   \
 \/___/  \___\ -> 3 1 or 1 3
  \   \  /   /
   \___\/___/
    ________
   /   /\   \
  /___/  \___\ -> 3 1 or 1 3
 /\   \  /   /
/  \___\/___/
\  /   /   /
 \/___/___/
    ____
   /   /\
  /___/  \
 /\   \  /\
/  \___\/  \ -> 3 1 or 1 3
\  /   /\  /
 \/___/  \/
  \   \  /
   \___\/
    ________
   /   /\   \
  /___/  \___\
 /\   \  /   /\
/  \___\/___/  \ -> 4 4
\  /   /\   \  /
 \/___/  \___\/
  \   \  /   /
   \___\/___/
      ____________
     /   /   /\   \
    /___/___/  \___\
   /   /\   \  /\   \
  /___/  \___\/  \___\
 /\   \  /   /\  /   /\
/  \___\/___/  \/___/  \ -> 16 11 or 11 16
\  /   /\   \  /   /\  /
 \/___/  \___\/___/  \/
  \   \  /   /\   \  /
   \___\/___/  \___\/
    \   \   \  /   /
     \___\___\/___/
      ____________________
     /   /\   \   \   \   \
    /___/  \___\___\___\___\
   /\   \  /\   \   \   \   \
  /  \___\/  \___\___\___\___\
 /\  /   /\  /   /   /   /\   \
/  \/___/  \/___/___/___/  \___\
\  /\   \  /   /\   \   \  /   /\
 \/  \___\/___/  \___\___\/___/  \ -> 40 20 or 20 40
  \  /   /\   \  /   /\   \   \  /
   \/___/  \___\/___/  \___\___\/
    \   \  /   /\   \  /   /   /
     \___\/___/  \___\/___/___/
      \   \   \  /   /   /   /
       \___\___\/___/___/___/
        ________________
       /   /\   \   \   \
      /___/  \___\___\___\
     /\   \  /\   \   \   \
    /  \___\/  \___\___\___\
   /\  /   /\  /   /   /\   \
  /  \/___/  \/___/___/  \___\
 /\  /\   \  /   /   /\  /\   \
/  \/  \___\/___/___/  \/  \___\ -> 46 18 or 18 46
\  /\  /   /\   \   \  /\  /   /
 \/  \/___/  \___\___\/  \/___/
  \  /\   \  /   /\   \  /   /
   \/  \___\/___/  \___\/___/
    \  /\   \   \  /   /   /
     \/  \___\___\/___/___/
      \  /   /   /   /   /
       \/___/___/___/___/
```

The output can be in any reasonable format, e.g. an array return value or a string with whitespace, but it must contains both values, even if they are the same, however the order of the two values does not matter in any way; you could even reverse the order on subsequent runs if you wanted to.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins!

Comment: One more maybe? Also http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8101/8478 ... I'd just put all test cases in one code block and the result for each on the next line.

Comment: Much better. I'd still put the results of the test cases on the next line though to make it easier to process them all automatically.

Answer (score 8):

## Dividing Strings

Division with numbers is great: `6 / 3 = 2`, but have you ever wanted to divide *strings*? In this challenge you will, given two strings (`s` and `t`) divide `s` by `t`

### Challenge

Given a string, `s`, find the substring in which `t` is repeated the most times (non-overlapping), return the amount of times `t` is repeated, example:

```
s = "HiFooFooFooFoo"
t = "Foo"
n = 4
```

Seems easy enough? Well if the substring **ends** with the first `m` characters of `t`, you should add what fraction of the string `t` was in the substring (`m/t.len`):

```
s = "12121"
t = "12"
n = 2.5
```

### Rules

- You only need to output to the precision your language supports. The minimum precision is two decimal places.

### Examples

First line is `s`, second line is `m`, last line is output. Examples are double-newline seperated

```
FooFooFoo
Foo
3
```

```
GoatGoatGoatGo
Goat
3.5
```

```
SheepSheepSheep
Goat
0
```

```
GoGoatGoatGoat
Goat
3
```

```
GoatGoGoatGo
Goat
1.5
```

```
ab111cd
1
3
```

```
PigPigPi
Pig
2.666666
```

```
aabaabaaaba
aaba
2
```

```
aabaaaabaaa
a
4
```

Comment: Here's a nice testcase: "PigPigPi" / "Pig"

Comment: what should "GoGoatGoGoatGo"/"Goat" return?

Comment: `"aabaabaaaba"/"aaba"-> 2`

Comment: Can the partial string at the end overlap with an occurrence of the complete string? (The intended answer seems obvious but it's not explicitly specified.)

Comment: @feersum Not sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/decimal-multiplication-of-strings)

Comment: @Downgoat _feersum_ probably meant something like this: `abaabaa`/`abaa` -> `aba|(a)|baa`, where the middle `a` is used as both leading/trailing part and thus overlaps (which I personally wouldn't allow for this challenge). Suggested test cases: `aabaabaaba`/`aaba` -> `1.75` (`...|aaba|aba`) and `121141115217`/`1` -> `3`

Comment: What about `wordwordstopwordwordwordword`. Would that be 2, 3, 5, unhandled, or something else?

Answer (score 8):

## Make A Full Dobble™ Deck

Dobble (A.K.A. Spot It!) is a deck of (**55**) cards each of which has a set of (**8**) distinct symbols, such that **every** pair of cards matches on **exactly one** symbol and all symbols are members of pairs.

[image: Dobble cards]

The base aim of any of the games one plays with a Dobble deck is to find the matching symbols between pairs of cards quicker than your competitors; if you've never played I recommend it.

The deck as sold contains **55** cards and uses **57** symbols, but it is actually a "Full Dobble Deck" of **57** cards with **2** missing. If the missing **2** cards were added there would be **8** distinct symbols on each card such that each symbol would appear **8** times across the deck. Here is a deck I've been playing with, each row being a card (with the **2** missing cards added and asterisked):

```
  Anchor     Apple      Bird       Dinosaur   Dolphin    Ghost      Ladybird   Turtle
  Anchor     Bang       Car        Clef       Flower     Key        Lips       Lock
  Anchor     Bolt       Clown      Glasses    No-entry   Snowman    Spider     Target
  Anchor     Bomb       Bottle     Dog        Heart      Ice-cube   Moon       Zebra
  Anchor     Bulb       Cactus     Dragon     Flame      Scissors   Sun        Tree
  Anchor     Candle     Clover     Hand       Man        Skull      Snowflake  Splat
  Anchor     Carrot     Cheese     Clock      Hammer     Knight     Maple      Web
  Anchor     Cat        Drop       Eroteme    Eye        Igloo      Pencil     Yin-yang
  Apple      Bang       Igloo      Maple      Moon       Scissors   Snowflake  Spider
  Apple      Bolt       Cactus     Car        Carrot     Heart      Pencil     Skull
  Apple      Bomb       Cat        Hand       Lock       Snowman    Tree       Web
  Apple      Bottle     Clover     Dragon     Flower     Hammer     No-entry   Yin-yang
  Apple      Bulb       Cheese     Clown      Drop       Key        Man        Zebra
  Apple      Candle     Clef       Clock      Dog        Eroteme    Flame      Target
  Apple      Eye        Glasses    Ice-cube   Knight     Lips       Splat      Sun
  Bang       Bird       Flame      Glasses    Heart      Man        Web        Yin-yang
  Bang       Bolt       Bottle     Clock      Dinosaur   Drop       Hand       Sun
  Bang       Bomb       Carrot     Clown      Dragon     Eroteme    Ghost      Splat
* Bang       Bulb       Dog        Eye        Hammer     Ladybird   Skull      Snowman
  Bang       Cactus     Candle     Cat        Dolphin    Knight     No-entry   Zebra
  Bang       Cheese     Clover     Ice-cube   Pencil     Target     Tree       Turtle
  Bird       Bolt       Bomb       Candle     Cheese     Eye        Flower     Scissors
  Bird       Bottle     Eroteme    Key        Knight     Skull      Spider     Tree
  Bird       Bulb       Carrot     Clef       Hand       Ice-cube   Igloo      No-entry
  Bird       Cactus     Drop       Hammer     Lock       Moon       Splat      Target
  Bird       Car        Cat        Clover     Clown      Dog        Maple      Sun
  Bird       Clock      Dragon     Lips       Pencil     Snowflake  Snowman    Zebra
  Bolt       Bulb       Clover     Dolphin    Eroteme    Lips       Moon       Web
  Bolt       Cat        Flame      Ghost      Hammer     Ice-cube   Key        Snowflake
  Bolt       Clef       Ladybird   Maple      Splat      Tree       Yin-yang   Zebra
  Bolt       Dog        Dragon     Igloo      Knight     Lock       Man        Turtle
  Bomb       Bulb       Car        Dinosaur   Knight     Snowflake  Target     Yin-yang
  Bomb       Cactus     Clock      Clover     Glasses    Igloo      Key        Ladybird
  Bomb       Clef       Dolphin    Hammer     Man        Pencil     Spider     Sun
  Bomb       Drop       Flame      Lips       Maple      No-entry   Skull      Turtle
  Bottle     Bulb       Candle     Ghost      Glasses    Lock       Maple      Pencil
  Bottle     Cactus     Clef       Clown      Eye        Snowflake  Turtle     Web
  Bottle     Car        Cheese     Dolphin    Flame      Igloo      Snowman    Splat
  Bottle     Carrot     Cat        Ladybird   Lips       Man        Scissors   Target
  Bulb       Cat        Clock      Flower     Heart      Spider     Splat      Turtle
  Cactus     Cheese     Dog        Ghost      Hand       Lips       Spider     Yin-yang
* Cactus     Dinosaur   Eroteme    Flower     Ice-cube   Man        Maple      Snowman
  Candle     Car        Dragon     Drop       Ice-cube   Ladybird   Spider     Web
  Candle     Carrot     Key        Moon       Snowman    Sun        Turtle     Yin-yang
  Candle     Clown      Dinosaur   Hammer     Heart      Igloo      Lips       Tree
  Car        Clock      Eye        Ghost      Man        Moon       No-entry   Tree
  Car        Eroteme    Glasses    Hammer     Hand       Scissors   Turtle     Zebra
  Carrot     Clover     Dinosaur   Eye        Flame      Lock       Spider     Zebra
  Carrot     Dog        Dolphin    Drop       Flower     Glasses    Snowflake  Tree
  Cat        Cheese     Clef       Dinosaur   Dragon     Glasses    Moon       Skull
  Cheese     Eroteme    Heart      Ladybird   Lock       No-entry   Snowflake  Sun
  Clef       Clover     Drop       Ghost      Heart      Knight     Scissors   Snowman
  Clock      Clown      Dolphin    Ice-cube   Lock       Scissors   Skull      Yin-yang
  Clown      Flame      Flower     Hand       Knight     Ladybird   Moon       Pencil
  Dinosaur   Dog        Key        No-entry   Pencil     Scissors   Splat      Web
  Dolphin    Dragon     Eye        Hand       Heart      Key        Maple      Target
  Flower     Ghost      Igloo      Skull      Sun        Target     Web        Zebra
```

This is actually a Full Dobble Deck of order **N=7**, where the order defines the number of :

- symbols (**N<sup>2</sup>+N+1**);
- cards (also **N<sup>2</sup>+N+1**);
- symbols per card (**N+1**); and
- cards containing any given symbol (also **N+1**)

A Full Dobble Deck is analogous to a [finite projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes) with points and lines as cards and symbols (or as symbols and cards) and thus may be constructed for any prime-power order (it is an open question whether finite projective planes exist for any non-prime-power order). We shall restrict ourselves to prime orders (it is much simpler to implement).

For example here is a Full Dobble Deck of order **3** (PG(2,3)) using **13** objects/colours (lines) and **13** cards (points) with **4** colours per card (lines incident with each point):

[image: Dobble-3 = PG(3,2)]

...and here it is as a list of cards containing the objects **[0,12]**:

```
[[2,3,8,11],[2,5,6,7],[1,2,9,12],[4,7,8,9],[4,5,11,12],[1,3,4,6],[0,6,8,12],[0,3,5,9],[0,1,7,11],[1,5,8,10],[6,9,10,11],[0,2,4,10],[3,7,10,12]]
```

#### The challenge

Given a prime (**N**) yield a Full Dobble Deck of that order in any convenient form.
**One must be able to observe completion for N=11** (no brute forcing here)
For any other input undefined behaviour is acceptable.

* You may alternatively take as input **N+1** or **N<sup>2</sup>+N+1**

---

[Here is a Python program](https://tio.run/##bVLLbtswELzrKxYOUFGxajQ5BvApaRv00Bh2bo4PlETVbChSICkHbtFvd5eUSElBeBGpnZ2ZfbRne1Ty9nIFP5@ev94Bl21noemMhYIBBcPlL8FAcMmAcMsaAw09u5jsmoJpA9TAGxPCfY3VCDfZ6lJr1QDCtVVKGOBNq7SF8ki5zKFUTcEltVxJkyQVq@FEBa@oZaRi5Wt2lwAeVfxmpTWwBsMs8ank2sczH@c1CCaJCza0JXjPoQ9nsF7DTc/ijkQOB3XR/ZdDBp/hJgaVrphGgLyWS7kc/w/0gwtPGTj8w@eNGu6UVFc75i0LbnpbaC/YmmE1s52WQIVwzsmQGmXcO4Na6UCa@wuOB/7wNsBNoIaXGTkeKqtITuETFH1TPCXNoXBM0zlMKG@Rz6XLJDlhKXE2fjUI1oGtOfWVtzhvSxbPR2pT3AT41uEiPKiiwJV5QGeganjyDf77b7VYoXhDLTkhBxOGfcQhlf2AZ7XILpf9Pt34bU1zSH/QE3Xf3RuvrbtsHjfpIYf3mF2peesBWw8vqaA97n659HkR/l35N9OiBzxS84qLPaZN5RD8HjSXc35mdINeMD5J3PaAbVecR6OxrkgQ4oFhrhcMBdQgF53H/kx8jNlR7v5qoBk7gr@m@UFgbNyklJAexxPkBxJfzOE/) that validates a potential Full Dobble Deck (it must be given as a valid list of lists in Python syntax such as the "list of cards containing the objects **[0,12]**" example above).

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Comment: You might want to consider some performance constraint which eliminates brute force approaches and forces people to think about the mathematics.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for having a look at this. I was thinking of having a "one must be able to observe it complete successfully for N=11" but if you have a more concrete idea for a constraint do let me know (maybe it should simply be "N=11 in one minute"? I should probably code something up in a less efficient language to try...) On another note I am also wondering whether to restrict the input from prime-powers to just prime as supporting prime-powers as well as primes adds some complexity to the requirements on the implementation; still mulling, any further input very much appreciated.

Comment: Observing it complete is preferable to "in one minute" because it means that if I have a slower computer it doesn't invalidate my answer, but merely slows down when I can post it. Using just primes is certainly much easier because there's no need to build field towers with irreducible polynomials. I personally would be much more inclined to answer if it's primes only.

Comment: [Related/dupe maybe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101229/9365)

Comment: @DomHastings weird I though, I'd searched both Dobble and Spot It, now I see two. The only things this would bring over the other code-golf question would be: (1) the alphabet there is bounded; and (2) implementing a constraint like Peter suggested. The current answer would need to iterate across (a least a large proportion of) the c(133,12) = 3.8*10^16 possible cards for N=11. I dont think (1) stops this being a dupe, but (2) might. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: @DomHastings Oh, and the brute-force solution there actually fails for N=4 (the first non-prime prime-power) even though I was planning on not requiring that to work the other (at present) does.

Comment: I only vaguely remembered it from when I first played Dobble too! Agree that the answer from the challenge I linked can't be copied over which I think is the main criteria for dupe, right? But the reverse might be true, all answers for your challenge should also solve the previous? So not sure if that make the older one a dupe, but that sounds too political for me!

Comment: If the input for this one is restricted to N being prime (or even prime-power) then answers to this would not necessarily solve the other. Furthermore while the other is limited to an alphabet of 62 (while I plan on an execution observation for N=11 which has an alphabet of size 133) answers to the other would not necessarily answer this one. Seems like maybe it's not a dupe after all, even though the premise is exactly the same!

Answer (score 8):

## Lucky Dice (KotH, WIP)

#### [CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92715/lucky-dice) • [CONTROLLER](https://github.com/ArtemisFowlJnr/Lucky-Dice)

You have recently taken a job at Lucky & Co, as a professional dice roller, and need to make as much money as you can! (of course). You will be paid exactly what you roll, $1 for a 1, $2 for a 2 etc. Where's the fun in that? Well, these aren't ordinary dice: starting with $5 in your bank, you must purchase new dice, which will all be rolled each turn. There are many different types of dice, all with different probabilities of rolling the different numbers. Every turn, you take a look at what the dices have done for you, then decide what to invest in. But beware! You have many rivals, all with the same aim in mind, and there are only so many dice in the shop...

### The Dice (StC)

There are many types of dice, which can be split into the following categories:

#### Basic Earners

20 of each are available, they are simply rolled and their value is added to the total points:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╦═══════╦═════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦═════╗
║ ID ║     Description     ║ Price ║  1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║ 4  ║ 5  ║  6  ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬═════╣
║  0 ║ Rolls a 1           ║     1 ║ 100 ║  0 ║  0 ║  0 ║  0 ║   0 ║
║  1 ║ Likely to be low    ║     3 ║  50 ║ 25 ║ 13 ║  7 ║  3 ║   2 ║
║  2 ║ Unlikely to be high ║     6 ║  22 ║ 22 ║ 22 ║ 11 ║ 11 ║  11 ║
║  3 ║ Even chances        ║     9 ║  17 ║ 17 ║ 17 ║ 17 ║ 17 ║  17 ║
║  4 ║ Unlikely to be low  ║    12 ║  11 ║ 11 ║ 11 ║ 22 ║ 22 ║  22 ║
║  5 ║ Likely to be high   ║    16 ║   2 ║  3 ║  7 ║ 13 ║ 25 ║  50 ║
║  6 ║ Rolls a 6           ║    21 ║   0 ║  0 ║  0 ║  0 ║  0 ║ 100 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╩═════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩═════╝
```

#### Multipliers

These multiply the points gained by the basic dice by something between 0.33 and 18... 10 of each are available. `r` represents what it rolled, each outcome (1-6) is equally likely:

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║   Description   ║ Price ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║  7 ║ Multiply by r/3 ║    10 ║
║  8 ║ Multiply by r/2 ║    13 ║
║  9 ║ Multiply by r   ║    22 ║
║ 10 ║ Multiply by r*2 ║    34 ║
║ 11 ║ Multiply by r*3 ║    50 ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

#### Attacks

These dice, with 10 of each available, are what makes the game truly interesting. They handle user interaction: each has a set action that it applies to one other random player (except 16):

```
╔════╦══════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║              Action              ║ Price ║
╠════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 12 ║ See below (too long)             ║    35 ║
║ 13 ║ They get 10 less (not below 0)   ║    45 ║
║ 14 ║ Like 12, but you get the points  ║    60 ║
║ 15 ║ They get 25 less (not below 0)   ║    60 ║
║ 16 ║ Like 14, but you get the points  ║    90 ║
╚════╩══════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

12: A fair dice, the value of which is subtracted from every other users' basic dice roll (not below 0).

#### Coins

Miscellaneous other bonuses and actions, each with a 50% chance of happening. There are only 3 of each available:

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║                Description                ║ Price ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 17 ║ Protects you from attacks                 ║    65 ║
║ 18 ║ Roll every basic die again                ║    90 ║
║ 19 ║ Roll every basic and multiplier die again ║   110 ║
║ 20 ║ Square your score                         ║   120 ║
║ 21 ║ Cube your score                           ║   170 ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

### How the dice fall

When working out the points for a round:

- Every players' coins are flipped. The results are remembered.
- Every players' basic dice are rolled (as many times as specified by coins). The total of the results for each player is that players' points for this round
- Every players' multiplier dice are rolled (with extra rolls). Each multiplication is applied on top of the previous one.
- Any squaring or cubing is applied.
- For every players' attack dice, a random other player is chosen for each. Unless that player had a shield, the appropriate action is taken.

### A game

A game lasts until first place is 200 points ahead of second place, or until 500 rounds have been played. There are 7 people in each game, who each start with just $5. Every round, each player submits a list of dice that they want to buy. If they ask for a dice that isn't there, ask to pay more than they have, or returns an otherwise invalid move, they do not buy anything that round. If more people ask for a dice than there are of that dice, no-one gets it. After every bot has given their move, and all orders have been resolved, the points for the round are calculated as above, and then added to the total score of each bot. At this point, the win condition is tested. 1st place gets 7 points, second gets 6 and so on. If two players are joined in, for example, 3rd place, they both get 5 points, but the next bot/s get only 3.

### A tournament

In a tournament:

1. If there are more than 7 bots, the bots will be divided into groups of 7 to play until every bot has played an equal number of games, and there are 7 bots which have a higher total score than the rest.
2. The top 7 bots play games until one has 50 more points than second place.
3. `2` is repeated for all the other groups of seven, and then the leftover bots. Now every bot knows its rightful place!

I will run a tournament every day if possible, which it hopefully will be.

### Coding

You will write a Python class that inherits from `Bot`, and implements `get_orders`, which must accept the following parameters:

- `money` - how much money each player has (a `tuple` of `int`s)
- `dice` - what dices each player has (a `tuple` of `tuple`s of `int`s)
- `index` - your index in the money and dice `tuple`s (an `int`)`
- `shop` - how many of each dice the shop has (a `dict` of `int: int` pairs)

Dice are represented in the above by their ID. You may also implement `__init__ (self, random)`, where random is a `random.Random` object, which is the only access to randomness that you are allowed, that is, if I were to run your code again with the same argument to `random` and the same calls to `get_orders`, I would receive the same results. You may also implement any other utility functions you wish. You may not store information between games (already banned but let's do it explicitly), and you may not mess with the controller. You may not team up (how could you?) or use any other competitor's code without significant changes without their permission. You may not programmatically invoke another competitor's code, because that could get circular...

### Controller

#### WIP

### Results

#### None yet ;P

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[probability-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

> ### *Sandbox*
>
> - *Any thoughts?*
> - *What should I clarify, I feel like I've missed everything...*
> - *Do you like the idea?*
> - *Have you spotted a perfect and unbeatable strategy?*
> - *Any suggestions for new dice/dice types?*
> - *Any suggestions for changes to the game/tournament system?*
> - *Are all the tags appropriate?*
>
>   #### Unicode Art Table

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║                Description                ║ Price ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 16 ║ Protects you from attacks                 ║    65 ║
║ 17 ║ Roll every basic die again                ║    90 ║
║ 18 ║ Roll every basic and multiplier die again ║   110 ║
║ 19 ║ square your score                         ║   120 ║
║ 20 ║ cube your score                           ║   170 ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

#### MathJax Table

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
\text{ID} &\text{Description} &\text{Price} \\
\hline
\text{16} &\text{Protects you from attacks} &\text{65} \\
\text{17} &\text{Roll every basic die again} &\text{90} \\
\text{18} &\text{Roll every basic and multiplier die again} &\text{110} \\
\text{19} &\text{Square your score} &\text{120} \\
\text{20} &\text{Cube your score} &\text{170} \\
\hline
\end{array}

#### Which is better?

Comment: Upvote this comment for MathJax tables.

Comment: Upvote this comment for Unicode art tables.

Comment: In your "Attacks" table, you want "`halve` their score" instead of "`half` their score."

Comment: I have given suggestions in the chat room

Comment: "A game lasts until first place is 50 points ahead of second place, or until 200 rounds have been played." Nobody will ever buy the big dice with this rule in play.

Comment: @Beefster Been running a few tests... I bot that just buys all the ID: 0 (roll-a-one) dice gets 20 per turn, and over 200 turns that's 4000 points. A few less to allow for the time it takes to buy them, and of course other bots will be playing, but still... I'll be thinking about it, and the *"first place is 50 points ahead of second place"* is definitely wrong.

Comment: Why not just cut out the "way ahead" end condition and just make it a constant number of rounds?

Comment: @Beefster The idea was that it *should* end with the way ahead condition, but the round limit prevents it from going on forever. I'm not sure about that anymore though.

Answer (score 8):

## Round away from zero

[Submitted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191241/52194)

Inspired by [Round towards zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/190670/52194).

Given a number input via any reasonable method, round the number "away from zero" - positive numbers round up, and negative numbers round down.

You can output a floating-point number with the decimal point (e.g. 42.0) if desired.

<sup><sup><sup><sup>why did i think this was a good idea</sup></sup></sup></sup>

### Test cases

```
-99.9 => -100
-33.5 => -34
-7    => -7
-1.1  => -2
0     => 0
2.3   => 3
8     => 8
99.9  => 100
```

Comment: It's a great idea, because truncation-based methods from the original won't work quite as well, but there's still plenty of room to be clever.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is a dupe, since most answers to this can be an answer from the inspiration but with `+sign(input)` tacked on. I think that may be competitive in too many languages.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Actually, that solution would give incorrect answers for all integers except 0.

Comment: The test case inputs may have a better coverage for all cases: [-99.9, -5, -2.0, -1.1, 0, 0.0, 1.1, 2.0, 5, 99.9].

Comment: @Joel That is true, and I guess also adding a check for being an integer is probably different enough in most languages? I'll leave my comment in case another similar problem emerges but it is likely that someone will make the same mistake I do, so it may be a good idea to specifically say this won't work in the challenge.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman brings up a good point though, what's stopping people from doing something like `+sign(input%1)` to trivialize the challenge? Maybe I shouldn't post this after all

Comment: @Value Ink The outcome of the modulo operation varies in different programming languages when a negative number is involved (see the big table at the right side of the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)). Your solution can only give correct answers in some languages. This is actually a good task to make people aware of that. By the way, the first and third test cases yield wrong results.

Comment: I really like this challenge. It is very easy to understand and the implementation is not as trivial as it initially seems. I do think that you should include some non-decimal test cases like @Joel suggested, such as `-5` and `5`.

Comment: @Jitse won't that be hard for people whose languages are strongly typed or something? Although I guess they can just do `-5.0` anyways. Ok, I've changed them.

Comment: You may add a note saying that the returned answer can be a float (like `5.0`) or an integer.

Comment: @Joel good idea. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I just wonder, is it appropriate for me to post solutions after getting involved in improving the challenge?

Comment: @Joel I'm not sure (I assume it's fine), but if the dilemma is nagging you I think it's best if asked as a separate meta post and not as a comment in here...

Comment: Now that this has been posted, it would be best to delete it, to free up space

Answer (score 8):

## [Pristine Polyglots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211839/pristine-polyglots)

Comment: Wow, pristine quines are already hard enough, and now you want it to be a polyglot too? Especially since polyglots often rely on one language ignoring the executing part of the other. Also, does it need to pristine in both languages, or both combined (i.e. removing a section can work in language A, as long as it errors in language B)?

Comment: @JoKing I have no issue with very difficult challenges :P Programs must be pristine in all languages used

Comment: Is an empty program a valid submission?

Comment: @thedefault. No, and in order to properly enforce the pristine requirement, I've made the minimum program length 2 bytes

Comment: Ok, so when removing any substring of length \$n\$, if the program does not do what it's supposed to do, does that count as a runtime error?

Comment: @Razetime I've edited the definition of an error, does it now answer your question?

Comment: Yep, clarified.

Comment: Won't the program `""` be trivially pristine in a bunch of languages?

Comment: @Sisyphus Yes it will be, and I'm having trouble preventing something like that. I'm thinking requiring unaltered programs to produce a non-empty output, but I'm not too sure about that

Comment: Your rules say that a nonzero exit code is considered an "error", and a pristine program has to produce some output. Since an exit code is a valid form of output by default, would `exit(12)` be a pristine program? Removing the `2` and changing it to `exit(1)` would be an "error" by this definition, right? You might want to clarify that exit codes aren't a valid output.

Comment: You might also want to clarify whether an infinite loop that produces no output counts as an error or not.

Comment: @water_ghosts I think the definition of error in the post already covers infinite loops ("fail to terminate [...] within a finite amount of time"), and yeah, I suppose that would technically be a pristine program, so the output requirements have been updated to exclude output to STDERR (or nearest equivalent)

Answer (score 8):

## Win the competition [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Write a Javascript anonymous function that, given two functions as strings, deterministically picks one as the winner and returns 1 if the first input wins and 2 if the second input wins. The choice must not depend on the order of inputs (that is, for any given input pair, the same program must always win no matter which one is first).

Every submission will be used to compare all unordered pairs of all solutions except self. Every time a program is chosen as the winner, it is assigned 1 point.

Submissions must not store any information between runs, interfere with the controller or somehow destroy my computer. There is no hard time limit, but intentionally creating an excessively slow solution counts as destroying my computer. Submissions must not duplicate other submissions or be longer than 200 KiB. Submissions must not rely on the input functions always halting (that is, they must not execute them or any parts of them).

You should give your submission a name (it should match the regex `[A-Za-z ]+` and not coincide with any other solutions).

Controller in a snippet:

```js
document.write(atob(`PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sPgo8Ym9keT4KPHNjcmlwdD4KCWZ1bmN0aW9uIGFkZFByb2dy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`.split("\n").join``))
```

This is tagged [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill). Whoever wins the most wins!

After posting this, I will post two example (community wiki) answers: one that compares in lexicographic order, and another that compares first by byte count, then in lexicographic order (the reason for posting *two* is that at least 3 programs are needed for anyone to get any points).

## Sandbox stuff

- How can I prevent the last answer from always winning?

  - Will that happen automatically, once enough answers are posted that it's nearly impossible to optimize for all of them?
- Would it be a good idea to introduce other requirements for the submissions, such as transitivity?
- Would it be a good idea to introduce a per-user submission limit (probably 1 or 2)?

Comment: That is a really fun idea but probably more a social- than a programming challenge:) I guess one problem is that newer submissions can always be tuned to favor themselves against all the existing ones, so it is probably gonna end up as a "last submission wins" if you don't include any counter measures.

Comment: I suggest a rule against randomness (and probably a language restriction, too, those make it a lot easier)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I can see why is randomness bad, but why should I add the language restriction? I have thought about it, and know I will probably add it in the end (because I can write an automated tester only in some langauges), but does it actually improve anything? (I guess I'll restrict to one of Javascript, C# or Python; Javascript seems to be the most common so it is also the most likely)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate No specific reason, but it tends to simplify things massively. It also allows the bots to more effectively read the source code

Comment: To minimise the problem flawr mentions you could consider only showing a "peek" of the programs to be judged, and then include a suitable upper bound on length. Of course, this has the problem of choosing that upper bound, but I think it may lead to a better back-and-forth? Posting will also still have a negative effect on your ability to win, however.

Comment: Some languages make extensive use of non-ascii characters, and some languages don't support non-ascii characters as input. Restricting the language is one way to solve this problem.

Comment: You should post it, just to see how it goes. Five upvotes just in the sandbox...if you added a language restriction and a few more rules to prevent the last answer from always winning, I think it'd be a popular challenge

Comment: Do we submit functions that take strings, programs that read from STDIN, or perhaps even functions that take functions?

Comment: I feel like the "no hashing" condition might be a bit problematic: For the last program submitted not to have an easy time with the rest, the scoring method of a program needs to be very hard to predict and game, and hashes are basically the optimal way about this. This then might end up with a challenge where people try to implement almost-but-not-quite hashing functions without upsetting you.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I see your point; removed the hashing restriction and also a loophole (where a solution that is a few GiB large, but presumably full of comments so that it doesn't run too slowly, makes all others time out).

Answer (score 8):

## [Inverted ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242174/inverted-ragged-list)

Comment: So, for `[[1,2],3,4]` is `[1,2,[3],[4]]` valid output?

Comment: Thanks @tsh, I added a rule against those kinds of lists

Comment: you can post alr 7 upvotes is plenty of community likes :) i like it tho anttiP gd job!

Answer (score 8):

## [Add a hidden language to a polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot/247976#247976)

Comment: "You can't reuse languages, but different versions of a language are considered different": How could someone reuse a language?  It would have to have two separate behaviors on the same program, which is just impossible. What does this rule do?  Why not just use the rules from the linked challenge?

Comment: @WheatWizard Oops

Comment: I'm a little concerned about someone using an obscure mixture of flags to hide from cops.  Maybe a rule that the specific language (including flags and options) must have been used in a previous PPCG answer would solve this?

Comment: @WheatWizard On second thoughts, maybe you have to reveal the flag combinations, like the Programming Language Quiz. Otherwise people *will* do stuuff like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/230585#230585)

Answer (score 8):

## [Is This an Equivalence Relation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251626/78850)

Comment: Do you have to explicitly take the domain? Can you assume all values in the domain appear at least once in the relation?

Comment: @CommandMaster no, because the relation may not be reflexive - it may not have `(a, a)` for all `a` in the domain

Comment: This seems to favor taking the relation as an adjacency matrix, since if you do that you can ignore the input domain. Can you choose to not take a domain, if you take an adjacency matrix?

Comment: @CommandMaster I think It's default that you may omit inputs you don't need.

Comment: @CommandMaster I updated the challenge to clarify adjacency matrices don't need the domain - only taking the relation as a set needs a domain input

Answer (score 8):

## Sʨɠɠanography

Many Unicode composed characters have two forms, one being a precomposed character, while the other is an ASCII character with a combining diacritic. For instance, `é` has Unicode code point U+00E9, but `é`, which looks identical, is actually the ASCII character 0x65 with the combining diacritic U+0301.

Your task is to write two programs or functions. The first will take a string of Unicode containing some composed characters and a string of printable ASCII. It will then output an identical-looking Unicode string which the second program can then decode to recover the printable ASCII.

By identical-looking, it must be the case that performing your choice of NFC or NFD normalisation on the input and output Unicode strings returns an identical string. If necessary, you may require that the input Unicode string be already NFC or NFD normalised (please specify).

If the input string does not contain sufficient composed characters for you to use, you should repeat it until its length is sufficient. You may also join the repeats with newlines should you so wish.

Your score is the sum of the byte lengths of your two programs divided by the number of composed characters you support in the input Unicode string. For instance, you may only wish to support those composed characters that expand to two characters under NFD. In this case your code's behaviour for other composed characters must be consistent (i.e. one of always unchanged, always NFC, always NFD). (Note that the Unicode string may also contain characters that do not change under NFC or NFD. You obviously can't use these to encode the ASCII string but they must still appear in the output.)

If your language supports arbitrary-precision integers, you may also elect to provide a demonstration of your algorithm on integers rather than printable ASCII strings.

Comment: "you may repeat it until its length is sufficient" - Do we have to, or can we assume that there are enough? If it's the first, "should" or "must" would be clearer.

Comment: +1 just because Sʨɠɠan

Comment: I feel so proud :p

Answer (score 7):

> **Note:** If you are seeing this first, you might want to [sort by active](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc).

### Unhappy numbers ascii art

Draw a square (or a rectangle as close to a square as possible) that represents the cycle of an [unhappy number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number).

[ short description of unhappy numbers here + example ]

[ square formating rules ]

#### Input

Unhappy integer.

#### Output

ASCII art.

#### Example

```
Input:
4
Output:
 4 -  16 - 37 
20         58
42 - 145 - 89
```

Comment: The cycle of an unhappy number is a constant.

Comment: @JB: thanks, I will rephrase the question. I didn't mean the 4 cycle.  (Why did I chose 4 as an example?  :/ )

Comment: @Eelvex This is an nice challenge. Are you still interested in finishing it?

Comment: This challenge proposal has been inactive for over a month. I would like to take ownership of the challenge and make it ready for posting. Please let me know within the **next 2 weeks** if you have any objections and would still like to finish and post this challenge yourself.

Comment: @JAtkin, no objections.

Comment: If this was posted, can you please delete it?

Answer (score 7):

## Objection! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

In the near future, the legal world is crumbling. If a case lasts longer than three days, the defendant is assumed to be guilty. Prosecutors create false evidence to get their guilty verdict or flawless record. Defense attorneys are forced to retaliate, claiming that the ends justify the means. In the trials and tribulations of the courtrooms of tomorrow, how will we ever get justice for all? This truly is the dark age of the law.

Luckily, the world has you. Just 11 short years ago, you were a ragtag rookie lawyer in a world of big fish, but you had potential and it showed. You always trusted your client, no matter how bad things looked. You were able to cut through the deception and reach the truth. When times got hard, you forced your biggest smiles. Of course, it was only 3 years before a little misunderstanding cost you your badge, but that's all cleared up now. You're back, ready to protect those no one else will and make miracles happen.

Except... You're pretty sick. For some reason you can't quite remember, you've got a crippling fear of cold medicine. Clearly, you're in no position to stand at the bench. If you can't be there to clear your client's name, you'll have to write a program to do it for you!

---

For this challenge, you'll be writing a program that can take your place in a cross-examination. There are three different things you need to keep track of: Facts, Evidence, and Statements.

- Facts

  - There are 26 Facts, named A, B, C... Y, Z. Usually, only a small number of them will be relevant, but you must be able to handle all of them if necessary. Contrary to their name, a Fact can be either True or False.
     
    You are never told the Facts, but you can figure them out from your...
- Evidence

  - Evidence is the most important thing for you to have, because it's how you know the Facts. You could make the case<sup>*</sup> that Evidence is everything in court. Pieces of Evidence have a name and a description of their relevance to the Facts. Evidence comes in two flavours: Direct and Circumstantial. Direct Evidence proves a Fact, while Circumstantial Evidence proves a fact if and only if a condition is met.
     
    You get your Evidence as input in this format:

    ```
    Direct Evidence
    Name of evidence: [Fact] is <true/false>.

    Circumstantial Evidence
    Name of evidence: If [Fact] is <true/false>, then [Fact] is <true/false>.
    ```
- Statement

  - A Statement is a declaration of Fact by a witness. There are also two kinds of Statements: Absolute and Conditional. An Absolute Statement claims a Fact, while a Conditional Statement claims a Fact if and only if a condition is met. Statements are taken as input in the same format as the second half of a piece of Evidence.

Your job is to analyze your Evidence to determine the Facts, then try to find contradictions in the Statements.

A Statement can contradict either an earlier Statement or a piece of Evidence. If a Fact is proven to be True or False and the witness claims the opposite, that is a contradiction. Note that `If A is true, then B is true.` and `If A is true, then B is false.` do **not** contradict unless `A` is true.

**Input**

Input comes from either `stdin` or a file, in exactly this format:

```
Evidence
<One or more pieces of Evidence on their own lines>
Testimony
<One or more Statements on their own lines>
```

**Output**

If there is a contradiction between a proven fact and something the witness claims, you must find the first Statement that contains the contradiction. If it contradicts the Evidence, output this:

```
Objection! Statement n contradicts this piece of evidence:
```

followed by a space and the name of the contradicted Evidence. `n` is replaced with the number of the contradicting Statement (starting at 1). If, instead, the witness contradicts themselves, output this:

```
Objection! Statement n contradicts statement m.
```

`n` is replaced with the number of the contradicting Statement and `m` is the number of the contradicted Statement (both starting at 1. m < n).

If there are no contradictions, output this instead:

```
No objections, Your Honor.
```

**Examples**

Input:

```
Evidence
My badge: L is true.
Thinker Clock: C is true.
Receipt: If C is true, then W is false.
Testimony
A is true.
B is false.
If A is true, then W is true.
H is true.
C is false.
```

Output:

```
Objection! Statement 3 contradicts this piece of evidence: Receipt
```

Input:

```
Evidence
Metal detector: B is true.
Testimony
If B is true, then A is true.
A is false.
```

Output:

```
Objection! Statement 2 contradicts statement 1.
```

Input:

```
Evidence
Stuffed animal tail: N is false
Testimony
A is true.
N is false.
```

Output:

```
No objections, your honor.
```

**Assumptions**

- The Evidence will never contradict itself. Evidence is infallible.
- There will never be a logic loop (e.g. `If A is true, then B is true.`, `If B is true, then A is true.`)

---

<sup><sup>* If you know what I mean</sup></sup>

Comment: Objection! According to the first example, `If A is true, then B is false` is equivalent to `If A is false, then B is true`, however this would cause the statement about contradictions incorrect. More detail on the first example: C is false, so the assertion from the Receipt doesn't apply; W is true, since A is true.

Comment: [Hold it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3R8tkvlAlk) The Thinker Clock found at the scene proves that C is true! Since we know C is true, the Receipt shows that W is false! The witness claims that A is true in the first line of their testimony, but then says that if A is true, W has to be true! By indirectly claiming that W is true, their testimony contradicts the evidence!

Comment: Wouldn't the Thinker Clock be the evidence being contradicted, then? There's more direct contradiction between the Thinker Clock and the last statement.

Comment: Of course, saying that C is False is a contradiction... [\*desk slam\*](http://i.imgur.com/3UWuPyA.gif) but the challenge requires you to find the first statement to contain a contradiction! [Present -> Challenge Spec] It reads, and I quote, ["...you must find the first Statement that contains the contradiction"](http://i.imgur.com/qt8FLlx.gif). Take that!

Comment: Ace Attorney strikes again!

Comment: So basically this is a presentation of 2-SAT. The third example is wrong: statement 2 contradicts stuffed animal tail. And I agree with Trimsty that where you have a chain of reasoning there isn't a unique "*contradicted Evidence*", so I think that you should make it clearer what you mean by that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I will figure out a way to formalize it better

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yep, my bad. That was a typo.

Comment: I feel like in many languages this scores for this will be dominated by string handling.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 7):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

## The Best Way to Rake Leaves

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

*[This is just a little problem I thought up while doing yard work today. It is not fully specified and I may not finish it if some simple optimal solution is found.]*

Suppose some 2D grid represents the area of a lawn. A number of leaves are strewn over the lawn and they are modeled as single grid points. You have a rake that is modeled as a line segment of length L.

[image: example]

To start you can rotate the rake in any way and put it anywhere on the grid.

When the rake is moved some distance d along its perpendicular, all the leaves in its path are caught in it. They stay on the rake line until the rake stops (as with normal raking).

You repeat this process (moving the rake different distances every time) until all the leaves all lie on one singular point.

The question is: what is the minimum distance the rake has to move to make this happen?
(i.e. what is the minimum sum of the d's from each move?)

## Challenge Spec (details incomplete)

Write a program that takes in a list of (x, y) leaf points and the length L of the rake (all floats).

The program should output a sequence of rake moves in the form of ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) line segments that the rake travels perpendicularly down the center of. This sequence must bring all the leaves to the same exact point when they are "moved" by the rake

The challenge is to make an algorithm that does this with the least possible sum of `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)` over all points.

*[At this point several test cases would be given, with different L values and different leaf distributions. The submission that minimizes the total distance wins (assuming they do not hard code the answer).]*

*[This optimization problem does not seem to have any trivial solutions or even a clear optimal solution. Can anyone else poke holes in it?]*

Comment: I still think this would be a fairly interesting problem. Any plans of still posting it at some point?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I have been trying to get around to it. If I don't in a week or so feel free to post it yourself.

Comment: No rush. I'd probably rather try to participate than post it myself. ;) I *am* considering posting something related though (it wouldn't be an optimisation problem, but it might be reusable as a substep for this challenge, although I'm not even sure it's anywhere near an optimal approach to this).

Comment: @programmer5000 Adopt it. That's fine.

Answer (score 7):

**Sandbox note:** This is an idea for a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge based on the halting problem. As it is, it's hard to imagine it being popular on PPCG, but I'd really like to make it into something people would actually participate in. The reason is that it's really interesting from a theoretical point of view, as a fundamentally open-ended challenge. The beautiful mathematics of Turing and Gödel gurantees that there's always a new innovation that the cops could make, and there's always a way for the robbers to exploit it. So any ideas on how to turn this into something fun would be greatly appreciated.

### HALT in the name of the law

The robbers are getting away, and the cops have to decide whether to wait for them to stop and arrest them, or set up a road block at the state boundary. They do this by trying to predict whether the robbers' program will halt. Please note that **this challenge is hard**, especially for the cops.

Robbers are represented by programs written in a language called "w", which I invented for this challenge, and which I describe below. w is easy to implement and relatively easy to reason about. I will provide a reference implementation and a macro preprocessor that allows it to be written in a somewhat human-readable form.

Cops must provide a program (in any language) that takes a robber's w program as input, and tries to decide whether it halts or not. A cop submission is invalidated by a robber program for which it returns the wrong answer or fails to terminate.

### Cops

You must write a program that takes as input programs in the (pre-processd) w language. It should attempt to output a truthy value if its input program ever halts, and a falsy value if it doesn't. Your submission should be written in a "real" programming language rather than w. In addition to your program, you should provide a clear English explanation of how it works.

### Robbers

You must "crack" cops' submissions by providing one of the following three things:

- A program written in w that halts, but for which the cop program does not return a truthy value. (The cops waited at the roadblock while you stopped, changed your identities and went underground.) You must demonstrate that the program halts, either by running it in the reference implementation of W or by proving that it has to halt eventually.
- A program written in w for which the cop's program returns a truthy value, together with a proof that your program does not halt. (The cops gave chase, but you kept going until you reached the state border, infinitely far away.)
- A program written in w for which the cop program itself doesn't halt, together with an argument showing that it doesn't halt. (The cops just gave up and got some donuts, hoping nobody would notice.)

### Other rules

If the cops' program is nondeterministic (e.g. because it's doing some kind of stochastic search for halting conditions) then it suffices to show that there is some non-zero probability that it will return the wrong answer or fail to halt.

This is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) for the cops - the uncracked submission with the most votes wins.

### The w language

**Syntax and semantics**

w is a very simple structured programming language whose variables can only be incremented and decremented, and whose only control structure is the while loop. The syntax is designed to be as easy to parse as possible. Here is an example w program. Below I'll describe what it does.

```
a+ a+ a+
b+ b+
a{
  a-
  b+
}
```

There is a preprocessor [to be provided] that, among other things, standardises the whitespace, so that the code above will be formatted like this:

```
a b
a+ a+ a+ b+ b+ a{ a- b+ }
```

The first line (provided by the preprocessor) is a list of all the variable names that appear in the program. All variables in w are unsigned infinite-precision integers. (Infinite precision means that they will never overflow. This is very important for Turing-completeness.) A variable name is any combination of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`. All variables initially hold the value 0.

The second line is a list of expressions. There are three kinds of expression. The first two are `<variablename>+`, which increments a variable by 1, and `<variablename>-`, which decrements it by 1. (For C programmers, think of these as the postfix `++` and `--` operators.) Since the variables are unsigned, it is an error to decrement a variable whose value is zero. This will halt the program immediately. (Note that errors are counted as halting for the sake of this challenge.)

The third type of expression is a while loop. Its syntax takes the form `{<variable_name>,<expression_list>}`. If the variable has value 0, the expression list is skipped. Otherwise, the expression list is executed repeatedly until the variable becomes zero. (If the variable never becomes zero, the program fails to halt.) That's it - there's nothing more to the language than that.

Note that if you split the second line of the preprocessed program at the spaces, each item will either be `}` or a variable name followed by a symbol, so you can easily pop off the last character to see what kind of expression you're dealing with.

Looking back at the example program, the first line, `a+ a+ a+` increments `a` three times, setting it equal to 3, and the second line sets `b` to three. The while loop decrements `a` while incrementing `b` until `a` is zero. So the value of `a` is added to `b`, and at the end of the program, `a` is zero and `b` is equal to five.

**Alternative syntax**

Optionally, the preprocessor can output w programs as a string representing a Python list. The example program would appear as follows. The first sublist is the list of variables, and the second is a list of lists representing the parse tree.

```
[["a", "b"], ["a+", "a+", "a+", "b+", "b+", "a{", ["a-", "b+"]]]
```

**Input and output**

For the sake of this challenge, we only care whether a program halts or not when given no input, so there is no input or output in the w language as described here. However, if we wanted we could say that a special variable (let's say `_`) is initialised with the program's input, and the value of the last expression evaluated is the output. If we do this, the language becomes Turing complete in the classical sense. (The proof is left as an exercise to the reader.)

**Implementation notes**

Implementing W correctly requires the use of infinite-precision integers. However, the only operations these need to support are incrementing and decrementing, which makes them much easier to implement. The reference implementation uses Python's unlimited precision integers.

Comment: As written this seems to allow `P` to fail to halt if the supplied program fails to halt. "*Completely define its syntax and semantics*" could lead to disputes, especially if someone chooses to use an obscure semantic model or to define their `L` in terms of an existing language which doesn't have formally defined semantics.

Comment: I think this will be way too hard on the side of the cops to be feasible for PPCG.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've fixed the first of those issues - do you have an intuition on how to deal with the second?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I like hard challenges, and by posting them I hope to attract other users who feel the same way. I think "this challenge is too hard" is not a thing that should be said here; it might seem hard to some people (especially before a solution has been posted) but one shouldn't underestimate how clever people can be. I'm not sure but I think being hard for the cops rather than the robbers is a good thing in this type of challenge.

Comment: I see this as much too easy for the cops, who can simply use a tedious integer factorization or similar task as always. Define *L* as follows: after performing trial division on a hard-coded integer, execute a Brainfuck program if it has a 200-digit prime factor, terminate without executing those instructions if it has a 201-digit prime factor, or otherwise go into an infinite loop. *P* simply prints 1.

Comment: Not really. You could pick a semantic model and require people to use it, but then you exclude people who don't know it and don't want to learn it just for this challenge. You could pick an `L` and require everyone to use it, but I expect you to say that that would take away a lot of the fun.

Comment: @feersum ah, you're right, this challenge can be gamed in that way. Even worse, you could use something like the twin primes conjecture instead of prime factorisation, and nobody could crack your entry without collecting a Fields medal. I'm not sure if there's a way to fix that :(

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd be quite happy to pick an `L` for everyone - that would also solve the problem feersum pointed out - but the question is, what should it be? It needs to be Turing complete and simple enough to analyse programmatically, and I guess it would help a lot if it was also fairly human-readable and intuitive. (That pretty much rules out lambda calculus, which is the obvious choice, though it's actually already a bit fiddly to deal with lambda expressions programmatically because of having to track free variables and do alpha-conversions all the time.) Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to take a functional approach then pick a universal set of combinators (e.g. SK or Iota). If you want an imperative language, either a well-specified BF or a "toy" language like IMP (as in the one described in Winskel's book on semantics, not the one described in the Wikipedia page - which might confuse people too much). Or pick something interesting from esolangs.org.

Comment: @PeterTaylor in case you're interested, I invented my own Turing-complete language (imperative but much more minimal and easier to parse than IMP) and added its spec to the draft.

Comment: Looks like a restricted form of Minsky register machine. As a fan of MRMs, I approve.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes, indeed, that's what I based it on.

Comment: A potential loophole for cops: The cops' program searches for a string that has a certain hash. If the string's length is more than 400, it outputs `true`, otherwise it outputs `false`. It would be very difficult for the cops to prove that the program generates an incorrect result.

Comment: In the non-preprocessed program, what whitespace is necessary? Is `a+a+a+b+b+a{a-b+}` valid?

Comment: @wastl not sure if I'll ever post this, but the preprocessor would ignore all whitespace, so that would be fine

Answer (score 7):

## King of the Sausage

*This is just a draft.*

I saw this (slightly altered) 'game' in a tv show once: Two competitors are each given a sausage of equal weight. Then they each have to cut pieces from this sausage (without seeing how much the oponent cut off) which then are weighted against each other. The player that has the heavier piece gets a point. Then the weighted sausage pieces are discarted and the process is repeated. After 5 rounds the one who got the heavier piece more often wins.

A win results in 3 points, a loss in 0, a tie in 1 for.

#### Details

Here the saussage weight is given as an integer `totalWeight`. You can only cut off pieces of integer size.

Each submission should write a JavaScript function that takes these arguments:

- `totalWeight`: The units of the total weight of the sausage at the beginning as an integer between `5` and `2^31-1`.
- `round`: An integer between 0 and 4 that indicates the current round.
- `ownPieces`: An array of size 0 upto 4, each element is the size of the piece you cut of in the previous round.
- `opponentPieces`: The same, but with the pieces of the oponent.
- `memory`: A variable that allows you to store information between the rounds. It can contain any kind of structure. It is initialized with `0` before the first game with an new oponent and it can store information between those games.

Each time it is called, it has to return an integer between `0` and the weight of the remaining sausage (= `totalWeight` minus the sum of the entries in `ownPieces`). If it does return anything else, the submission will be disqualified. The function may not access any global variables and may not try to influece the game in any other way. It cannot take more than 100ms per round.

Each pair of oponents will play this game a certain number (to be determined ) of times against each other.

Feel free to share your thoughts / suggestions!

## Meta:

How should the initial sausage weight be determined?

Possible controller inspiration: https://jsfiddle.net/CalvinsHobbies/ave6ejyd/

Comment: Are the weights integers or floats?

Comment: That is a crucial point thanks! The original game would obviously lead to using floats, but now that you ask, I think the integer problem would be even more interesting, don't you think?

Comment: I think using integers is good because it avoids discrepancies over parsing and rounding, but using small integers would allow a lot of pre-analysis to be done. I suggest starting at a random integer between 1000000000 and 2000000000 (within the range of signed 32-bit ints, but too large and variable to be easily pre-analysed). Oh, and if both run out of sausage then the remaining rounds should be ties. Allow a match to be tied, and score 3 points for a win and 1 point for a tie.

Comment: The clearest thing to me when competitors have no sausage is for them to tie the remaining rounds. I'm not sure if there is some other constraint you are thinking of, though. I also think I like Peter's idea of using a slightly random but guaranteed to be large sausage instead of a constant one. I don't think you would have any real problems given the size, but I think it would highlight the more interesting parts of the challenge.

Comment: If we have a variable saussage size, does anything prevent us to also throw in small numbers (at least the number of rounds)? As the competitors do not exactly know what numbers there will be, it seems it does not matter?

Answer (score 7):

## Ant Wars

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Parts of this challenge are based off of [Ant Queen of the Hill Contest](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5435/32700).

---

### Objective

Your objective is to conquer the ants of the world ... or have the biggest army of ants. To do this, you start with a single queen. The queen can create worker ants by using food gathered by itself or other worker ants. Your worker ants can kill other ants by attacking them. You win if you have the only queen left, or if you have the biggest army of ants.

---

### Board

The board will be a square with wraparound borders. The length of each edge is determined by `sqrt(1000*n)`<sup>1</sup>. Before the <s>game</s> fierce battle for domination starts, `100*n` pieces of food will be distributed semi-randomly on the board . `n` queens, 1 for each player, will also be randomly distributed on the board.

1: n is the number of starting players

---

### Ants

#### Sight and Smell

Ants are usually near-sighted and have somewhat short antenna. Because of this, ants in this simulation can only see and smell ants, food, and pheromone in its 3 by 3 neighborhood. They can also tell the difference between ants of different species.

#### Memory

Because of limited brain space, every ant has a memory of up to 5 characters long. The starting memory for queens is 5 spaces.

#### Orientation

Every ant is oriented in the direction that it last moved. Queens start out oriented in a random direction.

#### Food

Each worker ants can carry up to 1 unit of food. A queen ant can carry an unlimited amount (so that's what her body is for). Every ant picks up as much food on its current square as possible. A queen ant takes all the food from adjacent squares including that carried by workers of any player.

---

### Moves

Every turn, every ant is given a view of the local surroundings and then decides to move. Ants are given priority in their movement with those that are oldest moving first. The initial order for the starting queens is random.

#### Attacking

An ant attacks by attempting to move onto another ant. Worker ants require two ants attacking them in order to be killed. Queen ants require eight ants attacking it in order to be killed. Queen ants cannot attack. An ant after being killed drops all food it is carrying and one additional unit of food.

#### Moving

An ant can move to any of the 8 surrounding squares. This changes the orientation of the ant to the direction it is moving. If it tries to move to a square with an ant already on it, it is assumed to be attacking that ant, no matter if friendly or not.

#### Dropping Pheromone

An ant can optionally increase the value of 4 different pheromones on the cell it is on, 1 of which can only be seen by ants of that particular colony. Pheromone has a value of a double-precision float and decreases by 1% every game tick. An ant can increase pheromone by up to 10.

#### Creating Workers

A queen ant may create a worker and spawn it in any of the surrounding cells. The queen ant also chooses the memory of the new worker.

---

### Winning

A game ends after there is only one queen left or after 10000 turns. The winner is one of the players with a queen with the most workers. I will determine the winner after playing a number of games ... depending on the amount of time it takes to play each game.

---

### Coding

You can implement a program or a java class that takes in an ant input and gives an ant output for that ant.

#### Input:

Input contains your player id, your ant's memory, if your ant is a queen, and then the contents of the cells surrounding it. The cells are given from the top left to the top right in this order:

```
0 | 1 | 2
3 | 4 | 5
6 | 7 | 8
```

Input is format thus:

```
player_id;ant_memory;is_queen;cell_0_info;cell_1_info...
```

Cell info is formated like this:

```
pheromone_0,pheromone_1,pheromone_2,pheromone_3,ant_type,ant_owner
```

`player_id` and `ant_owner` are positive integers.
`ant_memory` is a 5-character long string.
`is_queen` is one of `true` or `false`.
The pheromones are double-precision (64-bit) floats.
`ant_type` is one of `W` (for worker ants) and `Q` (for queen ants).
If there is no ant on a cell, `ant_type` and `ant_owner` will be omitted from the input.

#### Output:

You have to output the cell you want to move to, the pheromone you wish to add to your current cell, and whether the ant would like to create an ant instead of moving (only works for queens :P).

It should be formatted thus:
    next_memory;cell;pheromone_0;pheromone_1;pheromone_2;pheromone_3;create_ant;created_ants_memory

The controller is rather flexible and should be able to understand what you write if you use different delimiters or leave out some of the information. Make sure that `next_memory` comes first in your programs output and that it is exactly 5 characters long. If creating an ant, `created_ants_memory` needs to be the last 5 characters in the input.

`cell` has to be an integer in the range [0, 8] (defaults to `4`).
`pheromone_n` has to be a positive float (defaults to `0`).
`create_ant` needs to be one of: `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, `1`, or `0`  (defaults to `false`).

#### How to create a bot:

You have 3 options for this. You can:

1. Implement the `Ant` interface with a java class. (**Very fast**)
2. Communicate to the controller via I/O streams.   (**Fast** (I think))
3. Be called via command arguments and output via STDOUT (**Slow depending** on OS and programming language)

**Note:** Your bot must be completely deterministic. Given the same input, your bot should always return the same output.

**Method 1:**

Ant interface:

```
interface Ant {
    String move(String input);
}
```

Implement this interface for your ants :)

**Method 2:**

Every time it is one of your ants' turns, your program will receive a line of input through STDIN followed by a newline. After receiving the input, your program is expected to output a line through STDOUT followed by a newline.

**Method 3:**

Your program will be executed with the input line as its first argument. Your program is expected to output through STDOUT.

#### Time limit

Each time your program is called, it should return within 5 milliseconds. Since the time limit may be exceeded due to fluctuations outside your control, an average will be calculated. If at any point the average is above 5 milliseconds and the total time taken by your program across all calls so far is more than 10 seconds, the relevant player will be disqualified. This means they will not be eligible to win, their ant function will not be called again during that game, and all ants of that player will instantaneously perish.

---

---

## Questions

1. How can I improve this to look prettier?
2. Any typos or formatting issues?
3. Any other ways I can improve this challenge?

Comment: What is `n`? Where do queens start? Go through everything as if you were writing the underlying code, and ask yourself "How would that be implemented?". It's a good way of making sure all the info is in there.

Comment: @TheNumberOne Could you put a link to / embed the controller? Or perhaps post this as an actual challenge?

Comment: @trichoplax Answered your questions in the post... though I am a little late :P

Comment: @BentNeeHumor Good to see we are both working at the same rate :)

Comment: In chatting about my ant KotH in the [dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62666/formic-functions) I remembered this version with pheremones that fade over time. I'd love to see this posted to main. Is there anything that needs to be addressed or anything we can help with?

Comment: (P.S. In case you hadn't seen it, mine finally made it to main after 2 years in the sandbox, back in July)

Comment: define "character" - is the memory ASCII-only? `\00-\ff`? any unicode character?

Comment: @trichoplax sorry, I haven't been active on here for a while. you can probably do whatever with it ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Simulate Colorblindness [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)[optical-char-recognition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optical-char-recognition)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

As some of you might know, I am [colorblind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness). Specifically, I have moderate deuteranopia. This means that I have difficulty distinguishing between red, green, and yellow colors, as well as various shades of purple and blue, due to not having green cones in my eyes.

The most common way to diagnose colorblindness is through the use of the [Ishihara test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishihara_test). In this test, various image plates are shown to the individual. These plates are comprised of dots of several shades of the same color, where certain shades are grouped together to form numbers. The shades are chosen so that, based on the set of plates on which the individual fails to recognize the number, the type of colorblindess can be determined.

Here are a few samples of Ishihara plates:

[image: plate 1]

This plate (plate #1 in the Ishihara 24-plate test) is a control plate - everyone should be able to see the number `12` clearly, regardless of whether or not they are colorblind. This is the only plate on which an individual with total colorblindness (monochromacy) can read the number.

[image: plate 2]

This plate (plate #2) has an `8` inscribed on it, but individuals with red-green deficiencies see it as a `3` (myself included).

[image: plate 8]

This plate (plate #8) has a `6` inscribed on it, but individuals with any type of colorblindness cannot see any number.

[image: plate 14]

This plate (plate #14) will be seen as having a `5` on it by individuals with red-green deficiencies, but others will not see any number.

[image: plate 16]

This plate (plate #16) has the number `26` on it. Individuals with protanopia will only see the `6`, and individuals with deuteranopia will only see the `2`.

### The Challenge

Given a set of Ishihara plates, output the number that an individual with each type of colorblindness (none, protanopia, deuteranopia, and monochromacy)<sup>*1*</sup> would see on the plate. Your score will be the number of correct outputs your program gives for each plate in the scoring battery (up to 4 points per plate).

For testing purposes, [here is an Imgur gallery containing the first 17 original Ishihara plates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUExB.jpg). The correct outputs for each plate are as follows:

```
X means that no number can be read
Plate #: Normal, Protanopia, Deuteranopia, Monochromacy
1: 12, 12, 12, 12
2: 8, 3, 3, X
3: 29, 70, 70, X
4: 5, 2, 2, X
5: 3, 5, 5, X
6: 15, 17, 17, X
7: 74, 21, 21, X
8: 6, X, X, X
9: 45, X, X, X
10: 5, X, X, X
11: 7, X, X, X
12: 16, X, X, X
13: 73, X, X, X
14: X, 5, 5, X
15: X, 45, 45, X
16: 26, 6, 2, X
17: 42, 2, 4, X
```

The scoring battery will be a unique set of Ishihara plates, created for the purpose of this challenge.

### Specifications

- Input and output may be in any reasonable manner and format, so long as no extra information (such as the number that should be seen on the plate) is conveyed in the input other than the image data.
- Builtins which trivialize this challenge (such as an optical character recognizition library like [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)) are forbidden. Though I highly doubt that any programming language or library has this functionality built-in, Mathematica and its ilk continue to surprise me.
- The scoring set of plates will not be disclosed, to prevent optimizing for that specific set.

<sup>*1: There are actually a few other variations of colorblindess, but Ishihara plates are not effective at diagnosing them.*</sup>

### Sandbox Questions

- Did I mess up any of the plate images? Being colorblind myself, picking out the proper plate images is rather difficult.
- Is there anything that needs further specification?

Comment: 1. There seems to be a reference to a footnote, but I don't see the footnote. 2. The descriptions of the plates seem to me ("normal") to match the images. 3. You do realise that the golfiest approach is likely to be to find a single pixel which differs in all the images in the test battery? I'd be rather surprised if any answer actually does OCR.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for reminding me to add the footnote. As for point 3, disallowing optimizing for the scoring cases takes care of that.

Comment: As usual with those kinds of classification challenge, the optimal way to provide data should be: a training set, a validation set, and a test set. You only provide the training and validation set, so that people can use the training set to build their algorithms and the validation set to check that they generalize properly. You keep the test set to yourself and use it to give a score to each answer, as such no one can optimize their algorithm to get the best score.

Comment: I agree with Fatalize regarding the hidden test set. Also, that plate #14 is blowing my mind (since I have no problems with vision, I've never experienced the "other" side of these sorts of tests).

Comment: @Fatalize I wasn't sure about how people felt about the scoring set not being public, but I will go along with that suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

## Natural Pi - The Front Nine W.I.P.

```
## Meta ## 
    - 4 more ways to calculate pi with nature?
```

---

## Introduction

These challenges are simulations of algorithms that only require nature and your brain (and maybe some re-usable resources) to approximate Pi. If you really need Pi during the zombie apocalypse, these methods don't [waste ammo](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/how-mathematicians-used-a-pump-action-shotgun-to-estimate-pi-c1eb776193ef#.eld2u7w76)! There are [nine challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10035/43214) total.

Each challenge will give an algorithm for approximating Pi with nature. Then it will walk through how the computer simulation should work. Next comes the Specification to clear up details and finally there are some test cases.

---

## [Natural Pi #0 - Rock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95231/43214)

- *Coprime Probability*

## [Natural Pi #1 - Sand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96275/43214)

- *Buffon's Needle*

## [Natural Pi #2 - River](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104655/43214)

- *Curvy-ness of a River*

---

## Natural Pi #3 - Books

- *E's in a circle*

## Natural Pi #4 - Sun Flower

- *Ratio of Area to Diameter*

## Natural Pi #5 - Vine

- *Period of a Pendulum*

## Natural Pi #6 - Fire

- *Ratio of Circumference to Diameter*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)

Comment: Please read http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8464/45941

Comment: @Mego my intention is to post these as distinct challenges and not a multipart challenge.

Comment: Then why is the [tag:multiple-holes] tag present?

Comment: @Mego Oops,  thanks for pointing that out

Comment: The "*probability that two random integers are relatively prime*" isn't well defined. You can't talk about a "*random integer*" without defining a probability distribution, and you can't uniformly select a random integer because there's an infinite number of them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good catch, I have specified an interval for the random numbers

Comment: Reusing sandbox posts like this doesn't really work. There are already 2988 answers in the sandbox: it won't harm to have one more, and it means that the new question can be commented on, voted ready, etc. independently of the previous one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point, I was originally tracking my ideas and hoping for recommendations on the set as a whole, but I'll migrate this to individual posts,

Answer (score 7):

### Give numbers space [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Given a list of integers, adjust each number by at most ±1 so that in the resulting list, each number is at least 2 apart from each of its neighbors. That each, each entry `n` can be replaced with `n-1`, `n`, or `n+1`, and any two adjacent entries `x` and `y` must have `abs(x-y) ≥ 2`. The output is a list of the same length as the input.

You will not get an input where this is impossible, such as `[5, 4, 4, 5]`. The input will have at least two elements.

Examples (other outputs are possible):

```
[-5, -6] -> [-5, -7]
[1, 1, 1] -> [2, 0, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 3] -> [3, 1, 4, 2]
[0, 5, -1] -> [0, 5, -1]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3] -> [5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5] -> [3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6]
[1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7] -> [2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6]
```

Comment: `[5,4,4,5]` is impossible I think. The two `4`s have to become a `3` and a `5` to not be close to each other, and then whichever one becomes a `5`, you can't adjust the other `5` away from it.

Comment: Maybe this could be a decision problem then?

Comment: I think this is viable to post as is?

Comment: @Razetime Do you prefer the current version where impossible inputs aren't given to the decision problem or some other alternative?

Comment: I like the decision problem version more. Another idea would be the shortest combination of adjustments to reach the final array

Answer (score 7):

[WHAT IS THIS DOING HERE?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/breadboard-challenges)

## How low can you go? - Signal Limbo.

Sometimes we need a low voltage, sometimes we need a high voltage.  Let's design a VDC power supply!

The challenge is simple, with 2 lines (+5V and GND), Create a Variable DC power supply on a standard breadboard that ranges from +12V (+/-0.1) to 0V.

**INPUT**: 5VDC (power rail +), 0VDC (power rail -), [5K](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cts-electrocomponents/026TB32R502B1A1/CT2158-ND/203779), OR [10K](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/PDB182-K425K-103A/PDB182-K425K-103A-ND/3780720) potentiometer

**OUTPUT**: 12-0VDC depending linearly on potentiometer. There is no lower limit to the ammount of current that this circuit needs to be able to supply.

**Rules**:

[image]

<sup>this is a standard breadboard. Image courtesy of [SparkFun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard)'s breadboard tutorial.</sup>

A standard breadboard consists of 2 power rails, 2 colums of 5 general pins, and 30 rows.

- All pins on one row (a,b,c,d, and e are all a single row) are connected.
- All pins on separate rows are Separate.
- The opposite is true for power lines. (columns are connected, but not rows)

Electrical components are restricted as follows.

- All electrical products which have a public datasheet are valid in this challenge, EXCEPT

  - Those without [DIP Packaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package) XOR Those without through hole packaging
  - Those with PCBs
- All Non-Passive components used in your entry must have a part number, or spec sheet.
- All passive components (except wire) must have a value, given in Ohms, Henries, or Farads.
- No pin may be left floating. All pins must be connected to somewhere on the bread board.

**Scoring:**

You will be scored based on the area that your entry spans. Do Not Score with the power rails, only components within the labelled grid shall be scored.

The area (measured in pin spaces) will be taken by the smallest rectangle that can be drawn around all of the breadboard connections.

this is a [breadboard-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breadboard-golf), so the entry with the least area consumed wins! good luck!

**Tools**

[Circuits.IO](https://circuits.io/) Will be a great standard for this challenge. I ask that you consider this before any other simulator, it's simple, and easy to share. I am not requiring that you use it.

Comment: To one who doesn't have experience with a standard breadboard, the "column" of 5 would better be described as a row, given the picture. This goes for everything in the first set of bullets - switch "row" with "column" and vice versa.

Comment: The description of how the breadboard is internally wired is not very clear, but seems to be saying the opposite of how every breadboard I've ever used was wired.

Comment: Alright, thank you Mistah, and Peter, I'll be sure to remedy these qualms tonight!

Comment: 1. "*that ranges from +12V (+/-0.1) to 0V*". Is the +/- there to allow for tolerances in component manufacture, to allow for smoothed oscillations in the output, or both? 2. The wiring explanation is still not very clear IMO. How about "*All pins on one row (e.g. 23a-23b-23c-23d-23e) are connected*"? 3. In the other meta question, validation was mooted as via Spice. I'm not familiar enough with it: is it capable of emulating any product with a public datasheet, or is there a conflict there?

Comment: @PeterTaylor spice is the framework for all modern advanced circuit simulators.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. In your answer to the other meta question, you said "*provided that each challenge specifies a freely available digital testing environment*". I don't see such a specification in this challenge, and it's not obvious that "*All electrical products which have a public datasheet are valid in this challenge*" is compatible with it. Does this question meet your own criteria for acceptability?

Comment: My bad: I mixed up two usernames starting with t. I think you still need to answer the question of how answers are verified, though.

Comment: What's the distance from column a to power -?

Answer (score 7):

## Tower Defense (Abandoned)

[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Anyone is free to take over this challenge and fork as necessary. Just give me credit ;)

---

[image: Tower Defense Example]

## [View it here](http://Beefster09.github.io/pcg-tower-defense/tower-defense.html) | [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80457/tower-defense)

Tower Defense is a format for casual games that was popularized in the Flash era. The player places towers that shoot down invaders moving along a predefined path.

## Overview

Two submissions will compete against each other to invade the other player's village without being invaded themselves. They will have the ability to place towers, upgrade them, and spawn invaders to attack the enemy village. The game will be simulated deterministically in a turn based fashion, with each player being able to do one action each turn.

The game board is made up of two paths, each 100 spaces long. Each player begins with 500 gold, which is used for building towers and spawning invaders; and 100 life. Your objective is to bring your opponent's life down to 0. If neither player has been defeated after 100000 turns, the winner will be the player with the most life at that point, with ties being broken by who has the most gold at that point. If, somehow, there is still a tie, the match will be considered a tie.

## Income

Every 10 turns, players will receive gold. Initially, they receive 10 gold, but this amount increases by 3 every 100 turns.

Each time you successfully get an invader through your opponent's defenses, your income increases by 1 and you receive a portion of your income proportional to how much HP the invader had left.

Each time one of your towers defeats an invader, you receive gold. (More on that below)

## Towers

Each space on the path can house one tower. There are 3 types of towers, which have a range and a power. It takes 10 turns for a tower to be ready after it is built. Towers can be upgraded either with a wider range or an increased power, in increments of 1. There is no hard limit to how many times a tower can be upgraded.

Range refers to how many spaces away from the tower that can be reached by the tower's abilities. A range of 0 means that only the space that the tower is on is affected by the tower's attacks.

Power has a different meaning depending on the kind of tower.

### Turrets

Each turn, turrets fire at the invader within range that is farthest along the path to your village. They deal damage equal to the tower's power.

Turrets begin with a range of 1 and a power of 1.

### Stunners

Stunners fire at the invader within range that is farthest along the path to your village. However, instead of dealing damage, they stun the invader for a number of turns equal to the tower's power. After firing, stunners cannot fire again for their power + 1 turns. Stunners will not fire at invaders that are already stunned.

Stunners begin with a range of 0 and a power of 3

### Bombs

When an invader is on the same space as the bomb tower, it triggers and deals damage equal to its power to all invaders within its range. After being triggered, it cannot fire again for another 5 turns.

Bombs begin with a range of 2 and a power of 2

## Invaders

Each turn, you may spawn an invader. At minimum, it costs 10 gold and has a base HP of 10. You can spend additional gold to increase its power:

- (1G) +1 HP
- (10G) +1 Defense (reduce damage taken by 1, but not lower than 1)
- (10G) +1 Stun resistance (reduces stun time by 1 turn)

You are limited on the maximum stats. You start off unable to boost stats, but every 100 turns, the maximum increases by 5

There can only be one invader on each space of the board and invaders cannot pass through each other. You cannot spawn an invader if there is already an invader on the first space of the board. Therefore, a potential counterplay from defenders to prevent massive hordes of invaders is to put stunners on the first few spaces.

## Coding

The main game / AI driver is [here](http://Beefster09.github.io/pcg-tower-defense/tower-defense.html) (still a work in progress)

Submission logistics TBD

Both players will have complete knowledge about the state of the game and will be allowed to maintain state from the beginning of the game. They may not directly modify the game state. Any attempts to do so will be disqualified as will any attempt to obfuscate such an attempt.

(api description will go here)

Defenders should return an object with an `action` property that is either `'build'`, `'upgrade'`, or `'destroy'`. Each requires some additional properties to be set: (will add later)

Invaders should return an object which contains any stat boosts desired: `hp`, `defense`, and `stunRes`.

Both defenders or invaders may also return undefined or null to indicate not taking an action.

AIs must return their desired action in less than 10 milliseconds, averaged over 100 turns. Invalid actions returned by the AI will be ignored.

## Scoring

All submissions will compete against all other submissions in a round-robin tournament. The bot that wins the most matches is declared the winner. In the event of a tie, the number of turns it took to win will be totaled for all winning matches with the smallest cumulative turn count to victory wins. In the unlikely event of a further tie, the turns to loss will be totaled for all losing matches and the bot with the highest cumulative turn count to loss wins.

Only one submission per user can be scored in the round-robin tournament.

## Rules

- No abusing standard loopholes
- No direct modification of the game state passed to you. It will *not* be defensively deep-copied. Don't obfuscate your code to try to hide state modification.
- Any uncaught exceptions will result in disqualification.
- Implementations must be totally deterministic, i.e. random number generators are only allowed if seeded consistently (either with a constant or with game state) and must use isolated random state which the other AI in play cannot access.
- Submissions shall include an explanation of the AI's strategy.

Comment: The biggest issue you are going to have here is balance.  Making sure that the towers are evenly balanced and that both sides have a decent chance at winning each wave (in order to discriminate who is better).  It may be worth building an actual simulation and actually playing the game before making it a challenge.

Comment: I'd argue that this is just a [tag:king-of-the-hill]. Cops-and-robbers have a drastically different posting format that you don't want, and we've already had challenges where there are [different types of submissions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots)

Comment: Why don't you allow towers to be adjacent?  It's easy to check if they have blocked all paths to the exist.  Modifying the number of turns between rounds is useless as far as I can tell. It's far more effective to have massive waves than trying to join waves together.

Comment: You should tag this with the language that submissions should be in.

Comment: What constitutes an "obfuscated submission"? This needs to be defined more clearly. Side note: some people tend to write (subjectively) obfuscated code in the first place.

Comment: You should specify the base of the logarithms used in your calculations.

Comment: "Each Defender will face off against each Invader (not including any submissions by him)" should probably be reworded into "Each Defender will face off against each Invader, excluding pairs with identical authors". I had a hard time understanding the sentence. Also, this rule will heavily influence the results. Someone might post multiple fantastic Defenders and a decent Invader, and their Invader will have an easier time than the rest because it doesn't have to compete against the state-of-the-art. I know what you were trying to achieve, but a simple "don't cooperate" would probably suffice.

Comment: How does the damage scale with the power, *exactly*? "Power affects damage for bombs and turrets" probably isn't clear enough. Also, what is the base power of the stunner? I'd recommend rethinking and rewording that section in general - it feels clunky to read.

Comment: Nitpick: a one-dimensional "grid" can be called a tape, for example.

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood the way invader stats work. I thought they were permanent buffs. I have removed the relevant comments.

Comment: Is the stat boost limit cumulative or per stat? If I have a stat boost limit of 5, am I allowed to spawn an invader with +5 HP, +5 Defense and +5 Stun Resistance?

Comment: For a similar challenge structure, see: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51029/31203

Comment: 1. The symmetry could be restored by making each entry both an invader and an attacker, with the win going to the first to wipe the other out. That introduces the need to balance your gold between attack and defence. 2. I'm not seeing any money awarded for destroying an invader. That's somewhat unusual for tower defence games. 3. There are some ambiguities. Does "*already-stunned invader*" mean previously stunned or currently stunned? Does "*an invader is immediately in front of them*" mean on the same square or on a square numbered one less?

Comment: @Alion an obfuscated submission would be one that deliberately tries to hide implementation details- especially if it tries to sneak in direct game state modification. For example, if you implemented a bot in JSFuck, that would obviously be obfuscated

Comment: @Alion Stat boosts are cumulative. For example, a 5 boost limit would mean you could not do +5 HP and +5 stun resistance, but you could do +4 HP +1 stun resistance.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think bringing in symmetry is a good idea and it's an idea I've toyed with. I've been having some serious issues coming up with good ways to make it hard for invaders to just hoard gold and then throw a crapton of strong invaders all at once. To me, that seems like the most obvious optimal strategy.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I fiddled around with the defender defeating invader awards and I felt it gave too much growth to defenders- so much so that invaders could never overwhelm them. I think symmetry would solve this issue.

Comment: I have been creating a KoTH tower defence challenge in the background for a while and was a little saddened that you have beaten me to the punch... however after reading your spec, I think the tower defence challenge I am working on will have sufficently different mechanics to allow for both challenges to exist without being duplicates. I just need to get it to the point where it can be presented here in the sand box. That being said, I look forward to participating in your challenge.

Comment: @Moogie: yeah. It's definitely a background thing for me too. I've mostly been working on other challenges that are friendlier to working on them during lulls at work. That, and my motivation is random and this challenge takes quite a bit more effort.

Answer (score 7):

## The Formic Forest - Ant QotH Contest

[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

---

## Overview

While the [ants of the highlands](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest) gather food and walk around each other, their distant cousins live in the forests below, growing fungus and aggressively raiding the ground and other nests for food. But like their highland counterparts, they want food, and they have armies of workers at their disposal to get at it.

### The Arena

The arena is a torodial 1000*2500 rectangular grid of cells. Each cell has one of eight colors, and at most one object at any one time. There are three types of objects of significance:

- Ants are either queens, which are spawned at the start of the game, or workers, which are spawned by queens.
- Food is a prized possession, and may be hoarded or consumed.
- Fungi are ant-placed objects which may be created at low cost and will grow slowly into food if left alone within the vicinity of food.

In this game, adjacency refers to being in the [Moore Neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) unless otherwise specified. Some rules instead specify the [von Neumann neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood).

### Game Overview

Each game, 16 submissions are put against each other in a game. If the competition has fewer than 16 submissions, all of them participate in a game, and if there are more, the 16 players are chosen randomly.

At the beginning of each game, each cell is reset to the color 0 (white), each submission used in the game has its corresponding submission object constructed, and 2500 food, and 16 queens are randomly scattered onto the map. Queens are very unlikely to be adjacent to food or other queens, but this is not a guarantee.

Then the game itself proceeds. The game lasts for 15000 turns, and each turn consists of the following phases, each of which is resolved concurrently in turn:

- Decide: Each ant's views are determined based on the current state of the arena and previous move history, and each ant's decision is determined and validated separately.
- Move: Each ant's decision is executed simultaneously, and the presence of multiple objects in a single cell resolved once all ants that decided to move into a cell have done so.
- Grow: Each object that can potentially change as a result of its surroundings has its neighborhood resolved, and the changes to the objects as a result happen simultaneously.

After the 15000 turns is up, the game ends. Submission objects are disposed of, caches trimmed down, food amounts logged, and the process started again if more scores need to be collected.

### Ant Senses

Each ant has a 5*5 area of sight centered on themselves. This area of sight is arranged to give the ants a relative sense of direction in the immediate term, but not innately in the long term. Ants can see the color of empty cells, and the properties of objects in filled cells, but not the color of filled cells.

Each ant also has an internal state that can take one of eight values. This state is internal to that ant, and to transfer information between herself and other ants or to remember more than this, she must position herself, drop payloads, or mark the ground below her, all which are subject to enemy interference.

### Ant Actions

Using their senses, ants can decide to move or drop payloads, and also color their current cell and change their current state simultaneously, once per turn. The coloring happens on the cell that the ant is currently in, before she moves.

Ants move orthogonally or diagonally one cell at a time. Worker ants are free to move into other cells at their own risk, but a queen may not move to a cell that her view shows is in the Moore neighborhood of a non-adjacent queen, nor to a cell that her view shows is in the von Neumann neighborhood of an adjacent queen. (However, it is legal for a queen to stay still on a cell adjacent to another queen.) Additionally, a queen without food may not move into a step into a cell already occupied by a laden worker, lest she step onto a laden worker that decides to stay still, which would without this restriction kill her.

Instead of moving, ants may instead drop a payload into an adjacent cell. Food payloads cost one food, and can only be performed if the ant is carrying food. Fungus payloads cost nothing, and may be freely placed. Ant payloads may be performed only by the queen, cost one food, and consistently result in a new loyal worker. It is legal to drop payloads on oneself, but this will usually result in the dropped object being picked back up or destroyed during collision resultion, to no substantive effect.

### Ant Lifecycle

Both queen and worker ants start in state 0. Worker ants are oriented such that their "from" cell is the cell the queen occupied when spawning the worker, while queen ants have a random initial orientation. From there, it is up to submissions to perform ant-specific initialization and differentiation if desired.

Once spawned, ants have an indefinite lifetime. Queen ants are guaranteed to live up to the end of the game, but worker ants may die by colliding with other ants.

### Ant Leeching

After movements and collisions are handled, a queen may neighbor one or more unladen enemy workers. If the number of such neighbors is equal to or less than the amount of food carried by that ant, then the queen loses food equal to the number of adjacent enemy workers. An unladen worker ant that neighbors one or more enemy queens that lose food this way gains one food. If a worker is next to multiple such enemy queens, she receives only one food, and one or more food is simply lost forever.

This transfer does not occur between allied ants. To perform such food transfers, you must command the laden ant to drop her food in an adjacent cell, and have another ally be in that cell to automatically pick it up.

### Fungi

Fungi are a means of spawning more food. Fungus farms may potentially lead to bountiful harvests for submissions that invest the resources to spawn, watch over, guard and harvest these fungi. They may also be strategically planted to obscure the ground or probe for food from a distance.

If food is within a 9 by 9 cell area centered around the fungus, then the fungus will grow. Internally, fungus takes 32768 steps to mature and spawn into food, and will gain 1 step per generation per piece of food placed in this vicinity. Therefore, placing more food in the vicinity of a fungus will speed up the fungus's growth, but will also make a nice feast for any ants that find it. If a fungus is not within the vicinity of food, it will not grow.

Growth stages are visible to all ants, and work as a coarse indicator of the age of the fungus. 0 means that the fungus has taken no steps toward maturity, 1 means the fungus has taken 1-7 steps toward maturity, 2 means the fungus has taken 8-63 steps toward maturity, 3 means the fungus has taken 64-511 steps toward maturity, 4 means the fungus has taken 512-4095 steps toward maturity, and 5 means the fungus has taken 4096-32767 steps toward maturity. (If a fungus completes all 32768 steps of growth, it matures into food in time for ants to see it as food the next turn.)

## Collision Resolution

As noted above, all decisions are executed at once, and collisions are resolved as they happen once surrounding ants have all their decisions executed.

### Ants

Collisions are an unavoidable consequence of multiple ants deciding to enter the same cell independently, or one or more ants entering a cell of an ant that decides not to move from it. Because ants may move only one cell at a time, up to 8 ants can move into the same cell at a time, and may run into an ant standing still in it. Queen-queen collisions are prevented by the rules restricting movement within the vicinity of other queens.

Collisions of ants are resolved depending on the ants involved. For the purposes of collision resolution, an ant is considered moving if and only if she spent her turn moving herself to a different cell. A newly spawned worker is treated like a moving worker.

- A queen, if involved in a collision, is always the only survivor. She loses one food if she moved to a cell containing a laden worker that stayed still. As stated previously, a queen without food may not move to a cell already occupied by a laden worker, preventing the case where an unladen queen would step on a laden worker staying still.
- The collision of more than one moving laden ants in a worker-only collision results in all involved workers dying, leaving food behind in the cell.
- If a still laden worker is in a worker-only collision with no more than one moving laden worker, she survives, but loses her food if there was a moving laden worker in the collision.
- If a single ant in a worker-only collision held food and she moved, then she alone is the survivor. She loses the food she carried if she moved onto a worker ant that stood still.
- If none of ants in a worker-only collision held food, then they all die.

### Food and Fungi

Fungi do not stack. If multiple fungi are placed into a cell at once, collision resolution proceeds as if only one were placed in. Putting fungus in a cell already containing fungus will destroy the old fungus and create a new one. Fungus is destroyed if it shares its cell with any other object.

A queen ant that stays or moves into a cell will pick up all contained and/or placed food in that cell. However, if a worker does the same, she can only pick up one of these pieces, and the rest are simply lost forever. If no ants are available to pick up the food, then only one food remains in the cell, with the rest lost forever.

## Submission

Each submission must be a Javascript class, with two methods holding special significance: a constructor, which is called once per game start to initialize each object before eachTurn is ever called, and an eachTurn method, which is called concurrently on all new ant views to determine what to do.

The constructor is given no arguments, while eachTurn is given to arguments, an integer corresponding to the current ant's state, and a 25-length view array.

A possible submission skeleton is as follows:

```
class MyAnt {

    constructor() {
        //TODO: You fill this in
    }

    eachTurn(state, view) {
        //TODO: You also fill this in
    }

}
```

### Input

The view array contains objects of the following form:

```
{
    contents: Integer representing the contents of the cell, 0 for empty, 1 for food, 2 for fungus, 3 for ant
    details: Object giving details about the cell contents
}
```

The details object yields further information about the object in the cell, and for each of the possible cell contents, it has the following forms:

- Empty Cell:

  ```
  {
      color: Integer from 0-7 inclusive representing color of the cell
  }
  ```
- Cell with Food:

  ```
  {} // Yes, an empty object
  ```
- Cell with Fungus:

  ```
  {
      stage: Integer from 0-5 representing fungus stage, a very coarse indicator of age and time to maturity
  }
  ```
- Cell with Ant:

  ```
  {
      queen: Boolean representing whether the ant is a queen
      friend: Boolean representing whether the ant is ally or enemy
      food: Integer representing the current food stores of that ant
  }
  ```

Each view object provided represents reflects the true state of a cell in the arena, albeit with incomplete information. The array itself always corresponds to a flattened 5*5 cell area of the arena centered on the ant, rotated 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees such that:

- For ants that have moved since spawning, either the cell to the top or to the top left correspond to the cell that the ant was in before the one currently inhabited
- For worker ants that have not moved since spawning, either the cell to the top or to the top left correspond to the cell that the queen occupied the turn she spawned the worker
- For queen ants that have not moved since spawning, the orientation is randomly determined at the start of the game and remains until the queen moves

Indices in the view array correspond to cells in english reading order:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

There is no means of getting orientation information definitively either form inside or outside, and it must be inferred by current state and surroundings.

### Output

The output expected of the eachTurn method is an object with the following fields:

```
{
    cell: (Mandatory) Integer in 0-8 inclusive, representing the cell to move to or to drop a payload to
    spawn: (Optional) If present, 0 for no payload, or 1, 2, or 3 for a payload of food, fungus, or worker, respectively
    state: (Optional) If present, an integer in 0-7 inclusive, representing the state to change to
    color: (Optional) If present, an integer in 0-7 inclusive, representing the color to color the old cell with
}
```

The cell is interpreted with the same rotation as the view. Output cells 0-2 correspond to view indices 6-8, output cells 3-5 correspond to view indices 11-13, and output cells 6-8 correspond to view indices 16-18. If you compare this to the index chart above, this is in the same english reading order as the view array provided.

### No Side Effects

Submissions may not make state modifications except to themselves, and should take care so that internal state modifications from calls to eachTurn are not visible from outside. Debugging submissions using input and output is allowed, but once submitted as an answer, they are forbidden. Attempting to use input or output in a submission will result in an error and disqualification until edited out.

### Consistency

Submissions are expected to behave deterministically, and the eachTurn function is expected to be pure, returing the same decision object for a given combination of state and view, regardless of how eachTurn was previously called or is currently being called.

Built-in functions may be called, if they are similarly externally pure. Math.abs() is fine, but Date.getTime() is not, for some examples. In particular, you are not allowed to call Math.random(). Supply your own pseudorandom numbers from constants, ant states, and ant views.

Unless you have a good handle on javascript concurrency and are willing to stress-test the code for concurrency bugs, I recommend using well-tested concurrency patterns and performing only idempotent modifications of objects, or avoiding modification in the eachTurn object altogether.

### Resource Limits

Each game submission starts with 1 second of reserve time. Each call to the constructor and eachTurn add 1 millisecond to the reserve time, then decrement from the reserve time the time they took to execute. Calls are memoized, and don't count against a submission if they are found in cache. If a submission exhausts its reserve time, it is disqualified.

Submissions are also limited to 64 Megabytes of memory at any one time. Unlike the time limit, this limit is not enforced automatically, but if a submission turns out to consistently hog memory during games it participates in, I will use a memory profiler to determine if this limit is exceeded.

## After Submission

### Disqualification

To keep tournaments running smoothly, submissions are disqualified if their submission performs an invalid action. Disqualified submissions will be excluded from future games within a tournament after a disqualification, and will be kept out of future tournaments until the problem causing the disqualification is fixed.

The following conditions are detected automatically, and therefore result in disqualification immediately:

- Exhausting reserve time, as described above
- Returning an ill-formed or badly typed object from eachTurn
- Throwing an exception from the constructor or eachTurn
- Attempting to spawn food or workers with no food
- Attempting to spawn a worker with another worker
- Attempting to move a queen too close to another queen
- Attempting to move an unladen queen to a cell containing a laden worker
- Performing input/output from submitted answers

It might seem harsh to disqualify for a single wrong move or bug, rather than consider it "no move" or ignoring it, but by insisting on correctness from entries, I can focus my efforts on keeping tournaments running quickly and smoothly. This is not supposed to be an additional challenge, so a reason is given for any disqualification, and an explanation given, with specific input and output given to help solve the disqualifying problem.

### Multiple Answers and Editing

You may provide multiple answers, provided that each one stands as a competitor in its own right, does not team up with other submissions, and at least in part is the product of your own substantive effort. You may take advantage of other submissions' weaknesses in an effort to achieve a higher score in comparison. Keep in mind that submissions come in, the chances of running into another particular submission will decrease.

You may also edit your submissions to tune them however you choose. There are no guidelines about whether to create a new post or edit a currently existing post; the choice is yours.

If you make a variation of another submission, remember to differentiate it, and if is derived from someone else's work, remeber to credit your sources.

### Scoring

At the end of a game, submissions are ranked on how much food their queens held at the end of the game. Submissions which score exactly equal to each other simply share the average of the ranks they would have if they scored differently from each other.

Submissions with the highest average rank over a multitude of games win. For this challenge, I will give out working first places from tournaments as scores accumulate enough significance that Dunn's test indicates that there is a single distinct first place with at least 98% confidence.

## Chat

For questions and extended discussion of this challenge, please use the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77728/the-formic-forest). Comments on this post are likely to be cleared up from time to time, while chat room text will be kept around permanently.

If you want to contribute to the specification itself, see the github repository hosting the latest changes to this specification, [right here](https://github.com/eaglgenes101/formic-forest-specification).

Comment: Chat room for this contest: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77728/the-formic-forest

Comment: Part of the complexity is making sure that the queen can't become a wrecking ball, but has clearly-defined restrictions so she can't be disqualified by no fault of her own. Take it from me, there's been more than a bit of arguing about how much the queen can and can't do.

Comment: Why are submissions a JavaScript class?  You have rules about side effects and consistency so why not just make a toy language that must be functionally pure to implement the ants?  Since the ants have a very limited view of the world it could easily be done with a fall through pattern matching.  This would have the added benefit that people wouldn't need to learn JavaScript to participate, they would need to learn the toy language but IMO the language could be simple enough that it could be completely understood from a short description.

Comment: I'm following the mold of the Formic Functions challenge. Javascript is a familiar language that has had thousands of dollars worth pumped into creating optimized implementations, and while it has its shares of impurities and quirks, it's old and widespread enough that its warts are well-known and well-documented.

Comment: @HatWizard If you have any suggestion you can make one, and then someone else may write a JS interpreter of that language. Or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/40808#40808)... well, almost all of those are esolang, nevermind.

Comment: I think that the choice of JavaScript was one of the mistakes of the original formic functions challenge.  The way I see it, it is like using a jackhammer to crack a nut, sure you can do it but Javascript is a lot of machinery for the task and some things you want like functional purity are lacking.  I'm not even specifically opposed to Javascript, I think that any other production programming language would be overkill for the task even if it had functional purity. I'm suggesting a small language that could be programmed in about 30 min and learned in about 2 min.

Comment: @HatWizard I can't imagine a language that takes 2 minutes to learn to be *nearly* enough. I'm not against this idea in general, though.

Comment: @HatWizard a learning time of 2 minutes and a language powerful enough to have many approaches to the challenge (i.e. so not just specialized for pattern matching (even if that's the best option out there)) don't go together. Sure, >90% of my FF pattern matching code is just a ton of (nested) `.map`s and arrays but others might prefer different styles (e.g. Alions framework was class based, others just went linearly). For the original FF I thought of making a language _specifically for **my** pattern matching ideology_, but gave up as the requirements for me to consider it usable were too big.

Answer (score 7):

## Game of Lives

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata) [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life)

In this [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), your goal is to create a GOL (Game of Life) pattern that creates the most live cells after \$n\$ steps. The twist is, you will be competing against 3 other patterns on the same playing field at the same time.

Here are the rules of the Game of Life, with a couple of additions:

- Each player's starting living cells will be a specific colour.
- Any live cell with 2 or 3 live neighbours will stay alive, otherwise they'll die

  - Note that 'neighbours' includes diagonals, so there are 8 possible neighbours for a cell.
- Any dead cell with exactly three neighbours will become a live cell with the colour of the most common neighbouring cell. If there is no majority, it will become a neutral colour, which won't count for further conversions.

  - 2 Reds + 1 Blue = Red
  - Red + Blue + Green = Neutral
  - 2 Neutrals + Red = Red
- The playing field will be \$x\$ by \$x\$, where each quarter of the field is each player's starting configuration.
- Cells outside the playing field will always be considered as *dead*, and cannot be resurrected.
- Each starting configuration will be flipped and rotated so the right and bottom sides face the enemy.

For example, if your submission was:

[image: Start corner]

And you plotted them against one another, the starting configuration could be:

[image]

Note how the bottom right isn't symmetrical, but still has the correct sides facing inwards.

Your submission should be a \$x/2\$ by \$x/2\$ GOL pattern that assumes it is in the top left corner.

Rounds will be run until only one competitor remains or the whole pattern repeats, where the competitor with the most cells when the pattern repeats is the winner.

#### Sandbox:

- I haven't decided yet what sizes the playing field should be (\$x\$), nor how long each game should run (\$n\$).

  - I was thinking about a 128 by 128 playing field, with 64 by 64 for each player. Is that too large or too small? For reference, the submission would be the size of:
    [image]
    with some gliders and stuff for reference. Is that too many or too little? I haven't really got much reference.
- I am working on a visual controller like the [Formic Functions question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135102)
- Overall winner? Check all combinations (way too much time as more submissions are added)? Tournament structure (multiple rounds per elimination)?

Comment: So... where's the programming part?

Comment: @Alion Your submission is a GOL pattern. I guess you could say you're programming in GOL

Comment: Fairy enough. I just think it's a missed opportunity. You could easily make it into a JavaScript competition, where programs just run multiple rounds of the currently planned game, having access to what happened last round, and thus being able to iterate on their patterns. You don't exclude anything - at the start, you're just going to get a lot of static entries (and I don't think anyone's going to be discouraged by the fact the they have to write `return` before their pattern).

Comment: Unless you want to see the best static pattern, full stop. I can see that being fun as well - my comment was just a suggestion.

Comment: 1) Is it just me, or is the example picture screwed up? The distances to the dotted lines don't match up. 2) My computer would greatly appreciate it if the side length of the board was a power of 2 - the closest size to that is 128x128. 3) You could make the game last until the pattern settles down, i.e. starts being periodic.

Comment: I don't know if the challenge is interesting or not, mainly because it's very unintuitive to "program" in GoL.

Comment: @Alion "best" static pattern? I think how a pattern behaves also depends on its opponents.

Comment: @Alion I've fixed the image and changed the field size to 128, thanks.

Comment: @user202729 It might not be intuitive, but it is [possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88783/76162). [*Very* possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11880/76162).

Comment: We need to clarify the behavior on the borders outside of the whole playing field. Does the grid extend indefinitely? Or does it wrap around? Or maybe simply hard dead cells (cannot turn to alive whatsoever) outside the given area?

Comment: @Bubbler *Cells outside the playing field will always be considered as dead, and cannot be resurrected.* Though wrapping cells might be interesting...

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that.

Comment: *If they are all different colours, then the cell will be randomly picked from those colours.* Given the nature of complex GoL patterns, I would suspect that one random cell choice can make a huge difference, so it might be nicer to keep the outcome deterministic and just kill such a cell.

Comment: @Laikoni For clarity: we're talking about cell *colors* being chosen randomly, right? While I agree that this could generate large bias within a single game, I don't think it matters in the grand scheme of things. As for the solution (if this is to be considered a problem) - breaking the GoL rules seems odd. For example, a 3-color blinker would just disappear. How about adding an additional, neutral color in that case? It would behave the same way that all the other colors behave, but wouldn't give any points to anyone. A 3-color blinker would lose its outer colors that way, but keep existing.

Comment: I like the idea of introducing a neutral color.

Comment: You should probably explicitly mention that GoL uses a Moore neighborhood (which includes diagonals), as opposed to a von Neumann neighborhood (which does not).

Comment: You might want to specify the tourney structure, which I'm guessing will be round-robin style. Will standings be based on total points over the whole event or number of wins (i.e. 1st is 3 pts, 2nd is 2, 3rd is 1, or something like that)? Might shape the design choices. For the other points, 128x128 seems a good size, and you could try running both wrapping and non-wrapping as separate tourneys (but twice the upkeep unfortunately).

Comment: 1) The game should last a fair bit, so that there's enough time for stuff to happen. I'd say somewhere in the range of 10-50x side length. 2) As for the side length itself, I don't have an issue with 64. 3) I think the optimal way to find the overall winner would be to repeatedly choose 4 random entries per game until either a set number of games or some statistical threshold is reached.

Comment: I've been giving some thought to the middle ground between a language specific KotH and a language agnostic KotH. Agnostic makes it open to more challengers, but makes much more work for the challenge author. Specific is easiest for the challenge author, but excludes people who don't know that language. I like this idea of having the entry be a configuration that could have been discovered using any language, but can still be run on a single language controller.

Comment: If the playing field wraps, the player can be approached from any angle. If the boundary is closed, the player is shielded on 2 edges. Will the player be able to design knowing which 2 edges those will be? This would require rotating each player according to which quadrant they start in each game. Alternatively the player can have a consistent orientation but which 2 edges are shielded will vary from game to game. You could even vary both if you wanted to encourage highly robust solutions. (You will be placed in a random quadrant with a random orientation.)

Comment: Another possibility is to place the player at a random position so they don't always have the same alignment with their opponent. So not just a random quadrant, but make each quadrant bigger than the player and position them at a random point within that quadrant. For example, 256x256 playing field, split into four 128x128 quadrants. Each player is a 64x64 region, positioned randomly in its 128x128 quadrant

Comment: For deciding how many games to run in a tournament, if you don't need to fix that number up front you could use the same approach as Formic Functions: I settled on running 6 tournaments in parallel (well, sequentially and keeping track of totals, with each game being counted towards one of 6 buckets, in rotation). This means that if player A is above player B in all 6 tournaments, they have a >95% chance of belonging above player B. So you can display a leaderboard which is the sum of all 6 tournaments, and display players in joint place if the ordering isn't yet unanimous.

Comment: This allows leaving the tournament running long term and regularly posting the leaderboard with some joint places, which gradually become distinct places the longer it's left running

Comment: Is this posted? I like it.

Answer (score 7):

### Make Spanish from Latin

*Note: In the final challenge \$N\$ will be a concrete number (I am thinking about 100), but while this is in the sandbox it is subject to change so I have left it as \$N\$.  Currently \$N=133\$*

---

This challenge is based off of a list of \$N\$ [Castilian Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language) words and the words they originate from.

You are to write a program or function which takes the origin word as input and outputs as close as possible the Castilian derivative.  Your program should be no longer than \$N\$ bytes.

### Scoring

To calculate your score run your program on every origin word and calculate the distance between your output and the correct answer.  Your score is the sum of all these distances.

The distance here is a modified version of [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance.  It is the same as Levenshtein distance except replacement steps that add or remove a diacritic cost only 1 of a step as opposed to their normal 2.  This is because if you guessed `á` instead of `a` that's not as bad as if you guessed `f` instead of `a`.

You can use [this code](https://tio.run/##rZGxTsMwEIb3PMUpqpQE3AHGiHSBhQGExFhV6BKdGgvHiWxHCImX6YQYGCo2xNYHC7ZbLFNWFtvf/fb957sW9SMJMU3zOdz2MA4DqQY1JU2L6g650lCWsMwvLTJwa7GKtCoBWEKeYcYg222ywjKzTJ7fAnPP74F7zx@BR8@fR/wVWHreBm48v3peJYm44tqgbMgVe28Ul2uYL6LTtTTRpeUKDFRwfiJIrk0LsaadGmk60nIsdVZAXpfGO78AQlVBbe9HCTIwmRdJUGffMKgLCC1zyo9UM8BIsmnO4BQ6Lnk3dravf5yN/fYvp30p7Nje9sQV0JuW1BPX5D70X5knRXoUJsw@xd22TxmkKPv0MJ90wAFdzO67TYgKalpyYSHIpPvZdchl1eFw8wCDnZaBGYyyGZV6jqwvZgs42E7f) to calculate the distance between two strings.

The goal is to have as low a score as possible.

---

### About the list

All of the origin words, spare 2, are Latin words (Late or Classical depending on the word).  The two exception is `ezkerra` (the origin for `izquierda`) which is of Basque origin and `brixta` (the origin for `bruxa`) which is of Proto-celtic origin.  It has been added as an extra curve-ball in case you can get all the others with a little space to spare.

Verbs are always in the infinitive form and nouns in the nominative singular.

The words are not chosen randomly but rather I have focused on choosing words that follow a number of simple rules.  The list is also organized so that words that undergo similar transformations are grouped together.  This is for your ease of use, nothing more.

---

### The list

```
imperatrix, emperatriz
cicatrix, cicatriz
actrix, actriz
matrix, matriz
carex, carrizo
radix, raíz
falx, hoz
fovea, hoyo
formica, hormiga
fodiare, hozar
folia, hoja
filum, hilo
filius, hijo
filia, hija
ficum, higo
filare, hilar
ficcare, hincar
afflare, hallar
fundus, hondo
profundus, profundo
fungus, hongo
fabulare, hablar
furnus, horno
bufus, búho
ferrum, hierro
fetere, heder
fagea, haya
faba, haba
facienda, hacienda
facere, hacer
fastidium, hastío
fastidiare, hastiar
factor, hechor
factum, hecho
tectum, techo
octo, ocho
octavus, ochavo
noctu, noche
lacte, leche
iactare, echar
coctus, cocho
dictatum, dechado
phalanga, palanca
capere, caber
sapere, saber
lupus, lobo
lacrima, lágrima
lacuna, laguna
eruca, oruga
pater, padre
mater, madre
liber, libro
thema, tema
theatrum, teatro
thesaurus, tesoro
thesis, tesis
thorax, tórax
aether, éter
anthropologia, antropología
orthographia, ortografía
sapphirus, zafiro
philosophia, filosofía
echo, eco
chalare, callar
chamaeleon, camaleón
chaos, caos
materia, materia
resistentia, resistencia
aurum, oro
taurus, toro
autumnus, otoño
canna, caña
annus, año
ungla, uña
plangere, plañir
stringere, estreñir
signa, seña
scribere, escribir
stare, estar
stabulare, estabular
stipare, estibar
stria, estría
strix, estrige
studiare, estudiar
stimulare, estimular
stillare, estilar
sternutare, estornudar
statuere, estatuir
spirare, espirar
sputare, esputar
spina, espina
speclum, espejo
spectrum, espectro
squama, escama
squamosus, escamoso
squalidus, escuálido
scalare, escalar
scandere, escandir
scutum, escudo
scutella, escudilla
scriptor, escritor
sobrina, sobrina
sobrinus, sobrino
secta, secta
sector, sector
sibilare, silbar
subire, subir
subito, súbito
suspirum, suspiro
subiugare, subyugar
corvus, cuervo
fossa, huesa
socrus, suegro
lupus, lobo
acutus, agudo
tecula, teja
apicula, abeja
flamma, llama
flammare, llamear
planus, llano
plagare, llagar
plorare, llorar
plovere, llover
plicare, llegar
clavis, llave
clamare, llamar
gladius, gladio
gleba, gleba
globus, globo
blandus, blando
blancus, blanco
brixta, bruxa
ezkerra, izquierda
```

Comment: I think it's interesting in that it should be near impossible to get a perfect score without built-ins. As a suggestion I'd remove the non-ASCII words, or at least normalise them, and perhaps not let \$N\$ be too high. Also, I wonder what the default cat program would be.

Comment: @JoKing I am looking to somewhat twart perfect scores,  I feel there should always be some room for improvement,  It just is a little hard to balance this with golfing-languages ability for expressiveness.  I am interested to hear what ranges for \$N\$ you think are too high.  I started out by avoiding any non-ASCII characters, but it was really hard to build up a representative corpus of words.  Plus the accents and eñe really are a feature of the language.  I may adjust the scoring so that `i` and `í` for example are only half away from each other so that the penalty is small.

Comment: Suggested title: **Hispanize these words**. Also mention that words should be in lowercase. Finally I think it makes more sense to restrict programs to \$N\$ *characters* rather than \$N\$ bytes.

Comment: I'm not a fan of "Your program should be no longer than N bytes". I think a scoring rule which incorporates both the Levenshtein distance and the byte count would be better, as in the [Moby Dick challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152856/86301): it would allow more languages to compete, and would allow for more creativity.

Comment: @RobinRyder I think that metrics that combine two non-obviously related factors such as in the Moby Dick challenge or as you are suggested rarely work.  In fact I can't even think of an example I feel is good.  They simply require fine tuning that can only really be done in retrospect.  I also don't know how this would allow more languages to compete and I certainly don't know how it would "allow for more creativity".  If you have a specific metric in mind and a compelling reason why that metric would not be broken I would be happy to try it out and see.

Comment: Sorry, I'll expand: with a low, hard limit on the number of characters, non-golfing languages don't stand a chance (hence the "more languages" part). If instead you set a high hard limit, it will be possible to reach a (near) perfect score, with no incentive to golf or search for trade-offs (hence the "creativity" part). There surely exists a sweet spot for the character limit where neither of these issues arise, but (a) it will be hard to find and (b) it will be highly language-dependent.

Comment: @RobinRyder I think that 100 characters is plenty of characters for nearly any language to implement something a bit more complex than cat (e.g. replace `^f` with `^h`).  I also think that it would require quite a few characters any language to acheive a perfect score.  More than half of the words have seemly random vowel mutations that are not covered by any general rule.  The only way I can see a perfect score is a compression decompression method. It seems to me to write the de-compressor and make up for the loss would require a deal of room.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I think that sweet spot is actually very large.  And I think that adding more dimensions to the problem only increase the risk of missing the sweet spot.

Comment: Some possible typos (I'm a native Castillian Spanish speaker and I'm familiar with Latin): `afflare, hallar`; `factor, factor`; `chalare, callar`

Comment: @LuisMendo `hallar` and `chalare` are definitely typos.  But `hechor` was intentional.  I suspect your hang up is that `factor` and `hechor` are doublets but `factor` is more similar to the Latin.  There are plenty of words here for which the Latin is not a direct translation or the Spanish or vice versa (even factor is not).  I chose to include `hechor` because it is a good example of some of the changes that I want to highlight, (`f` -> `h` and `ct` -> `ch`).

Comment: The thing is, I never heard _hechor_. But I just checked in the [dictionary](https://dle.rae.es/hechor?m=form) and it is included, albeit as an old form, not in current use

Answer (score 7):

## [Complete the landscape](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/261484/66833)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35704/45613)

Comment: I'd recommend allowing the golfer to choose any three consistent distinct values for Field/Road/City

Comment: Why does the tile information need to include the number of cities? Shouldn't just the edges be enough?

Comment: @Jacob "As the number of cities on a tile is redundant for this task, you may choose instead to only work with 17 tiles (as 2 tiles are duplicated when ignoring cities) and take input as lists in the form [N, E, S, W] instead, giving this list of tiles". The original description of tiles came from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205861/score-a-1-player-game-of-carcassonne)

Answer (score 7):

## [Output a unique sign sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217175/66833)

Comment: Is shortness of the answer not supposed to be a factor at all? That is, we don't try to golf our answers? Even more, are voters supposed to consider just the sequence, or the code producing it? I'm not quite sure if "How clever is the implementation" is meant to apply to the code itself or just the general strategy.

Comment: @xnor No, golfing your answer is unimportant, but perfectly acceptable. Voters should consider both the code and the sequence, but primarily the sequence. The code should mainly be considered for how "elegant/clever/good" the vote perceives it to be. "How clever is the implementation" kinda applies to both the code and the strategy. Using language-specific tricks are a reason to consider code "clever" as is implemented a fully generalised method that any language to pick up and use with no trouble

Comment: I think this works much better as answer-chaining than as pop-con. As evidence I'd say that almost half of the challenge being devoted to explaining the voting rather than the challenge isn't a good sign. I think looking at recent successful pop-cons shows that pop-cons are generally only good if the task just won't lend itself at all to another scoring criterion. This, at least to me, seems like a great idea for answer-chaining.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I do dislike the fact that this is a pop-con, and the only reason it is, is because I couldn't find any other criteria which would inspire the creativity in sequences I'm looking for (e.g. the reductive attitude of code golf would make this very boring). The issue I see with making it answer chaining is that the winning criteria is a bit iffy. "Second-to-last" isn't the best winning criteria as already discussed on meta, but it gets even worse when new answers aren't more difficult than previous ones, as the challenge will continue ad infinitum until (cont)

Comment: (cont) people get bored and stop posting, rather than new answers are genuinely too difficult to make. There are an infinite number of sign sequences, so "running" out isn't an issue, and each new answer isn't more difficult because there are so many to choose from. Furthermore, I don't think it'd inspire the creativity I'm looking for. I don't think it'd be as bad as, say code golf, but I feel like people will resort to posting basic sequences in order to keep the chain from dying, thus extending it way beyond being fun

Comment: I had initially thought that preventing the obvious abuse cases was relatively simple (no prefix/suffixes and not periodic) but I've realised that it would actually be much more difficult than that. I still think this probably works better if massaged into something that works for answer-chaining, but you are probably right that it isn't as good a fit as my first impression was.

Comment: This might be interesting as a [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenge, though it would have to be a finite slice of an infinite sequence in that case.

Comment: @Beefster I think the only (or maybe best) way this could work as a CnR is where the cops reveal their code+language (and maybe a few terms of the sequence) and the robbers have to find the generating function for that sequence, but that would almost definitely lead to obfuscated code, rather than „how is the sequence generated“ being the focal point for answerers, which pivots away from the main idea of the challenge being interesting sequences, not interesting code

Answer (score 7):

## Possible binaries

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) <s>[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)</s>

---

This challenge is inspired by the AoC 2020, [Day 14 - Part II](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/14#part2), created by [Eric Wastl](https://twitter.com/ericwastl) and [his team](https://adventofcode.com/2020/about), which asks to output the possible binary values from a bitmask.

Let's say we've a bitmask like `"10X0X0"`, then we've to find the possible binary values that can be generated by replacing an `X` with either `0` or `1`.

So, the possible binaries are `["100000", "100010", "101000", "101010"]`.
When each of them are converted in decimal, then these are `[32, 34, 40, 42]` respectively.
And, finally the sum is `148`.

## Test cases

```
INPUT: "X"
["0", "1"]
[0, 1]
OUTPUT: 1

INPUT: "0"
OUTPUT: 0

INPUT: "1"
OUTPUT: 1

INPUT: "1X0"
["100", "110"]
[4, 6]
OUTPUT: 10

INPUT: "1X0X1"
["10001", "10011", "11001", "11011"]
[17, 19, 25, 27]
OUTPUT: 88

INPUT: "X0X0X0X"
["0000000", "0000001", "0000100", "0000101", "0010000", "0010001", "0010100", "0010101", 
"1000000", "1000001", "1000100", "1000101", "1010000", "1010001", "1010100", "1010101"]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 64, 65, 68, 69, 80, 81, 84, 85]
OUTPUT: 680

INPUT: "1X1X1X1X1X1X1X1X1X1X1"
OUTPUT: 1789569024

INPUT: "1X01X01X01X01X01X01X01X01X01X01X01X0"
OUTPUT: 201053554790400

INPUT: "X000X000X000X000X000X000X000X000X000X000X000X000"
OUTPUT: 307445734561824768

INPUT: "101"
["101"]
[5]
OUTPUT: 5

INPUT: "XXX"
["000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
OUTPUT: 28
```

## Rules

- It is guaranteed that \$ 0 \leq \text{count}(X) \leq 12 \$ and \$ 1 \leq \text{length}(mask) \leq 48 \$.
- Input can be either a string, or an array of chars (non-empty).
- Output will be the sum of the binaries in decimal.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

---

### Meta

- Is the challenge's text clear enough?
- Is the constraint on count of X sufficient?
- Although I've tried a search, but is this a duplicate?
- Any suggestions/improvements in the attribution?
- Any tricky test case?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the size of an input bitmask? It would probably be good to provide one, but if there’s intentionally no upper bound, you should have a test case where the input is longer than 64 bits.

Comment: What about empty lists? (I'd like to have it as undefined, so we don't need to handle that special case). I believe the `permutation` tag doesn't apply here. And maybe an example for `XXX`?

Comment: @water_ghosts - Yes, there is an upper bound, I've edited that.

Comment: @xash - No, there will be no empty list/string. Added the example, and striked off the tag for now, but maybe it could be related somehow..

Answer (score 7):

## [Calculate longest Stack Exchange streak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222876/calculate-longest-stack-exchange-streak)

Comment: I'd say the best input format would be nested maps/dictionaries/whatever in the language's most normal data structure with the schema given in the input format, or alternatively (i.e. leave it up to the answerer), the exact text format you gave above (minus the `var visited = `).

Comment: I think for a [tag:internet] challenge in general it is fine to ask for the input data to be parsed after collecting it from the internet. I'd expect most of the variance to come from trying to find shortcuts in parsing in this case anyway. Finding users who are good test cases might be tricky - so perhaps including some made-up results which test basic stuff (skipped months/years, February) could be nice. I don't know that CGSE is new enough to not have any weird calendar stuff (missing days, etc.) that should be specified.

Comment: Not sure why, but if I go to `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/daily-site-access/66833` (my user id is 66833), I just get a blank page? Challenge-wise, I think that this is pretty clear, and I agree with the other commenters that the default format is perfectly fine. You are missing an [objective winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria) however

Comment: Thanks for your input! @ChartZBelatedly it's a blank page indeed, but viewing the source helps. It was intended to be a [code-golf] challenge, I assumed that was the default. I'm missing test cases too, of course.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 7):

## [Did I die or not?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223994/did-i-die-or-not)

Comment: Perhaps add a few cases to make sure solutions check for exactly 12 wrong guesses? Like `"ABCD...Z", "L" -> True` and `"ABCD...Z", "M" -> False`

Comment: @ManishKundu Added

Answer (score 7):

## [Backronymiser឵឵](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249788)

Comment: I quite like this challenge, but why are there four possible outputs for `xxxx, X`? Was it not specified that the *first* occurrence should be capitalized and only that one?

Comment: I'll change it so that it's always the first option.

Comment: May we take a list of words as input? A list of characters? Or a list of lists of characters/character codes? (I think it's [not covered by the I/O link you provided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A2447+string))

Comment: @pajonk I think it's generally understood that a string and list of characters are interchangeable. But I'll add notes about the other two.

Answer (score 7):

## It almost works (C&R)

### [Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231321)

### [Robbers thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231322)

Comment: Looks really fun!

Answer (score 7):

## Stronger and stronger radiation

This is a [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge where answers create successively more radiation-hardened programs.

The first answer will be a program that is at least 2 distinct bytes long that outputs `1`, with an optional trailing newline, and nothing else. However, when any single character is removed, it should output `0`. For example, if `abc` outputs `1`, then all of `bc`, `ac` and `ab` should output `0`.

The second answer should then be a program that is at least 3 bytes long, with at least 2 distinct bytes, that outputs `2`. When any single character is removed, it should output `1`, and when any 2 characters are removed, it should output `0`. So if `abcde` outputs `2`, then:

- All of `bcde`, `acde`, `abde`, `abce` and `abcd` should output `1`, and
- All of `abc`, `abd`, `abe`, `acd`, `ace`, `ade`, `bcd`, `bce`, `bde` and `cde` should output `0`

And so on such that the \$n\$th answer is a program that is at least \$n+1\$ bytes long, with at least 2 distinct bytes, that outputs \$n\$. When any \$k\$ bytes are removed for \$1 \le k \le n\$, it should output \$n-k\$.

Languages may be reused, but not in consecutive answers. Different versions of the same language count as the same language. You may not answer twice in a row, and you must wait an hour between answers.

The last answer posted is the winner. This will update as new answers are posted, but the latest valid answer will be considered the current winner.

---

## Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- Tags are [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining), [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening) and [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). Any others?
- Any additional feedback?
- I'm concerned that this might be too difficult, and so it's unlikely that more than 2 or 3 answers will be posted. I'm considering changing it to:

  > The \$n\$ answer is a program that is at least \$n + 1\$ bytes long that outputs \$n\$. When any \$n\$ bytes are removed, it should output \$n-1\$

  Thoughts?

Comment: An answer isn't allowed to read its own source code, right?

Answer (score 7):

## [Fill in the next numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243764/fill-in-the-next-numbers)

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be "Fill in the gaps with previews" (previews because the gaps contain the next number to be seen, so the gaps "preview" the sequence) but it also sounds rather strange.

Comment: I would like to exclude the "prime" part in the example. It makes me confuse this challenge is about doing something to test a number is prime or not.

Comment: Also, instead of show gaps as numbers, underscore could be less confusion, as `_ 2 3 _ 5 _ 7 _ _ _ 11`. And say any gaps (underscore) should be filled by right hand values.

Comment: I agree with @tsh that I wouldn't mention 'primes' since it might lead to confusion. The example could still be `2,3,5,7,11` and people can see for themselves they're primes, but I just wouldn't mention this explicitly. So the sentence "_For example, if the input is the first 5 prime numbers:_" would be: "_For example, if the input is:_" and `# primes` in the code block would be `# input`. Apart from that it's a great challenge, and I've already prepared a solution for when it goes to main in the near future. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Laggy text editor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243614/laggy-text-editor)

Comment: Your example only submit an input after hitting Enter. Am i required to follow this behavior or may I consider each key press as an input?

Comment: @tsh I'm not quite sure how to deal with "prompting for input" in general, but I guess you can take each key press as an input if you want.

Comment: [A fiddle which delay every input 5 second](https://jsfiddle.net/6zegdjfq/)

Comment: @tsh Thanks! (filler)

Answer (score 7):

## [Collatz Encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246722/collatz-encoding)

Comment: What should the input 0 output?

Comment: @BgilMidol "Your challenge is to write a function or program which takes an integer (n>0) as input" i.e. 0 will never be an input

Comment: oh, i didn't see that

Answer (score 7):

## [Eh, codegolf shmodegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247751/92689)

Comment: Nice idea! You probably want a general procedure people can follow to do this, and I don't think the initialisms is a good idea.

Comment: @emanresuA You're probably right about the initialisms. I added an example of an ungolfed python function that solves the challenge, and some restrictions on the input. Do you think more things should be specified?

Comment: This looks fine! Leave it for another day or two though just in case.

Comment: I suggest adding some more test-cases (especially starting with more than one consonant). Also, re: last sentence - definitely specify what to expect as input (only letters? at least one vowel? will the input start with a vowel?) and add some test-cases accordingly if necessary. In the end, please clean up the post (one can view edit history if interested in the evolvement of the question), so we can see what you intend to post and maybe give some feedback on that.

Comment: I recommend stating the rules of shmification used in this challenge explicitly - I guess this will be three points (to present briefly): 1. consonants up to first vowel replaced with shm; 2. prepend shm to words beginning with vowel; 3. no vowels = no shm. Also, I suggest altering the example program to actually solve the challenge or removing it altogether to avoid confusion.

Comment: @pajonk Thank you, excellent points. I have added rules and updated the code to solve the challenge as it is stated.

Comment: You should specify that vowels are specifically `aeiou` (and not `y`). Also, can we assume the input only contains lowercase letters?

Comment: @pxeger The input being lowercase letters is already specified, but I moved it and added a line about what the vowels are, thanks :D

Comment: Maybe some words on output formats? People will wonder whether they can output as a list with two elements, a function that returns two words, or whether it has to be a single string joined with a space.

Comment: @chunes I changed the output to be a single string containing the reduplicated version of the input, that way it is clearer what format the output should be.

Comment: After the change, rule 3 no longer makes sense. Instead of saying "only repeated,"
 maybe "unchanged" or "leave it alone"?

Comment: @chunes You are completely correct, thanks! I have changed rule 3 to say that words without vowels should be returned unchanged.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Comment: @Steffan thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Race some Robots

<sub>Based on [RoboRally](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18/roborally), but uses some different/simplified rules</sub>

In this KoTH, you will be coding a Python bot that attempts to race around a factory, reaching two specific places before the other bots, who are doing the same thing.  The way you'll reach these places - the "checkpoints" - is by sending instructions to the bot, telling it where to move.

### The Factory

The factory is represented by a \$13 \times 10\$ 2D list, where each cell has a different component, each represented by a 2 character long string. The factory will be constant for the KoTH, and is the following 2D list (coordinates are shown around for reference):

```
    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
0 [['  ', '  ', '> ', '  ', 'vv', 'C2', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '^^', '  ', ' ' ],
1  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'vv', '  ', 'lv', '< ', 'l<', '  ', 'R^', '<<', '<<'],
2  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '<<', 'R<', '  ', 'v ', '  ', '^ ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '*v'],
3  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'lv', 'r<', '  ', 'r^', '< ', '< ', 'l<', '  '],
4  ['PA', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'lv', 'r<', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '^ ', '  '],
5  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'v ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'r>', 'l^', '  '],
6  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'l>', '> ', '> ', 'rv', '  ', 'r>', 'l^', '  ', '  '],
7  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'v ', '  ', '^ ', '  ', 'R>', '>>'],
8  ['  ', '  ', '  ', '>>', '>>', 'Rv', '  ', 'l>', '> ', 'r^', '  ', '^^', '  '],
9  ['  ', '  ', '> ', '  ', '  ', 'vv', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'C1', '^^', '  ']]
```

We will use compass directions in the explanations to refer to the direction a bot is facing, with "North" being the top of the factory (so \$(0, 0)\$ is the North-West corner).

This is fairly complicated, so we'll go over what each string means:

- : This is just a blank square. Nothing special happens.
- `C1`/`C2`: Checkpoints 1 and 2. You must visit Checkpoint 1 first, then Checkpoint 2. The first bot to do both wins.
- `>` /`<` /`v` /`^` : These are conveyer belts. At the end of each "register" (explained below), they move any robot on them one square in the corresponding direction.

  - For example, if a bot is on \$(5, 6)\$ at the end of a register, it is moved to \$(6, 6)\$.
- `r>`/`r<`/`rv`/`r^`/`l>`/`l<`/`lv`/`l^`: These are corner conveyer belts. If pushed onto these squares by a conveyer belt, the bot is rotated 90 degrees clockwise (`rX`) or counter clockwise (`lX`). At the end of each register, any bot on them (not bots that were just moved onto them) is moved one square in the corresponding direction.

  - For example, if a bot is moved from \$(6, 6)\$ to \$(7, 6)\$ while facing North, it is rotated 90\${}^\circ\$ clockwise and now faces East.
  - If this same bot then doesn't move during the next register, then it is pushed South to \$(7, 7)\$, facing East.
- `>>`/`<<`/`vv`/`^^`: These are double conveyer belts. If a bot is on one of these at the end of a register, it is moved once in the corresponding direction, and the conveyer square it lands on then moves it a second time
- `R>`/`R<`/`Rv`/`R^`: These are corner double conveyer belts, specifically right turn corners. As with normal right corner conveyer belts, they rotate a bot 90\${}^\circ\$ clockwise when pushed on to, but they then immediately move the bot in the corresponding direction.

  - For example, a bot facing South who ends a register on \$(11, 1)\$ would be pushed once to \$(10, 1)\$, rotated to face West, then pushed to \$(10, 0)\$.
- `*v`: This is the Reboot square. If a bot moves off the board, it is "rebooted": it receives 2 Spam cards, is placed on this square and all remaining instructions are ignored for this round. The bot is now facing South, and, if another bot is rebooted while a bot is on this square, the first bot is pushed one square to the South.
- `PA`: This is the Priority Antenna. It cannot be moved, you cannot move into the square, and is used to determine who acts first each round.

### Gameplay

Gameplay is very simple. The game is broken into rounds, and one round is structured as follows:

- First, play order is determined. Bots act in inverse order to their [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) to the Priority Antenna, with ties broken by the bot with the most "horizontal" (East-West) distance going first.
- Then, each bot is dealt 9 "programming cards" from their hand (initially 20, but it can grow). Each "programming card" contains a single instruction for the bot (e.g. Move 1, Left Turn, etc.). The bots then simultaneously<sup>*</sup> each choose 5 cards, discard the other 4, and order the 5 chosen from 1st to 5th.
- There are now 5 *registers*, one for each chosen card. A register proceeds as follows:

  - The card for each robot for that register is revealed, and the instructions are executed in play order.
  - Once all instructions are resolved, the conveyer belts all activate, potentially moving any bots.
  - Then, each bot fires a laser, in a straight line in front of it, until it either hits another bot, a wall, the Priority Antenna or misses all other bots.
  - If a bot is hit by a laser, it receives a Spam instruction, which is added to its "programming cards".
  - If a bot is on Checkpoint 1, it is now able to visit Checkpoint 2 to win. If it is on Checkpoint 2, it wins.
  - The next register begins, and the process is repeated.
- After all 5 registers are completed, and everything is resolved, each deck of programming cards are reshuffled with all programming cards, and the next round begins.

If a bot moves into the same square as another bot, that bot is pushed back one square in the direction the first bot is moving. For example, if Bot 1, facing East, moves from \$(7, 4)\$ to \$(8, 4)\$, and Bot 2 is already in \$(8, 4)\$, then Bot 2 is pushed to \$(9, 4)\$. Note that, if pushing a bot would push it into the space of another bot, both are pushed.

<sup>*</sup>: For the purposes of the KoTH, each bot will be given their cards, and will return their chosen instructions in some arbitrary order.

### Programming Cards

Each bot has a deck of programming cards, initially 20. The decks are all identical, and consist of:

- 3 Move 1 cards: the bot moves forward one square
- 2 Move 2 cards: the bot moves forward exactly two squares
- 2 Move 3 card: the bot moves forward exactly three squares
- 3 Right Turn cards: the bot stays in place, and rotates 90 degrees clockwise
- 3 Left Turn cards: the bot stays in place, and rotates 90 degrees counter clockwise
- 3 U-Turn cards: the bot stays in place and rotates 180 degrees
- 2 Move Back cards: the bot moves moves backwards one square, without rotating
- 2 Again cards: the bot repeats the previous instruction

  - Note that these don't "stack": playing an instruction, followed by 2 Agains does the instruction a total of 3 times, not 4

Additionally, bots can increase the number of cards in their deck by taking damage from lasers, or by rebooting. In this case, they receive Spam cards, which are added to their deck:

- Spam cards: a random card from the bot's programming deck is chosen, and that is the instruction carried out this register. At the end of the round, the Spam card is removed from your programming deck.

  - Note that this *does* stack: if the drawn card is a Spam card, you repeat until a non-Spam card is drawn. All drawn Spam cards are removed from your deck.

### Starting positions

Finally, we come to the start. At the very beginning of the game, the 6 players are placed on the 6 starting positions, in a random order. The positions are \$(1, 1)\$, \$(0, 3)\$, \$(1, 4)\$, \$(1, 5)\$, \$(0, 6)\$ and \$(1, 8)\$. Each bot may choose which direction they begin facing.

---

### Challenge

You are to write a function in Python 3 that takes the following arguments:

- `round`: an integer, beginning at `0`, counting what round the game is on
- `order`: an integer from `1` to `6`, indicating the bot's order of play, with `1` being first and `6` being last
- `position`: a 3-tuple `(x, y, d)` consisting of your zero-indexed coordinates in the factory, and a character, one of `NESW`, indicating the direction you're facing
- `score`: a boolean, indicating whether you have landed on Checkpoint 1 yet.
- `cards`: a list of 9 two character strings, indicating the cards you've been dealt

  - `M1`/`M2`/`M3`/`MB` indicate Move 1, 2, 3 and Back respectively
  - `RT`/`LT`/`UT` are Right, Left and U-Turn
  - `Ag`/`Sp` are Again and Spam
- `bots`: a list of 3-tuples `(x, y, d)` of the coords and directions of all other bots
- `factory`: the factory matrix above.

It should then return the following:

- If `round` is `0`, it should return one of `N`/`E`/`S`/`W` to indicate its starting direction
- Otherwise, it should return a list of up to 5 of the strings from `cards`, indicating its registers. Note that the first element of this list will be the first register, the second the second and so on. If you return fewer than 5 strings, the list will be filled with randomly drawn cards from your programming deck that weren't in `cards` until there are 5 elements.

Once the first bot finishes a register on Checkpoint 2, after its `score` is `True`, the game is finished, and the winner receives 1 point.

### Scoring

Every combination of 6 bots will play 3 games together. The winner of a game receives 1 point, and the bot with the most number of points after all the games wins.

---

### Example Bots

*Sandbox note: once I've written the controller, I'll add in a couple basic example bots*

#### `random_bot`

A completely random bot, it shuffles the cards dealt and returns the first 5:

```
import random

def random_bot(round, order, position, score, cards, bots, factory):
	if round == 0:
		return random.choice('NESW')

	random.shuffle(cards)
	while cards[0] == 'Ag': random.shuffle(cards)
	return cards[:5]
```

---

### Example round

*to be added*

---

## Sandbox

- Thoughts?
- Is this clear enough?
- The original game of RoboRally is super dynamic. I worry that bots may not be able to handle that without being super complex. Thoughts?
- Is this a dupe?
- Tags are [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game), [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid), [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) and [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python). Suggestions?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: [Feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62526428#62526428)

Answer (score 7):

## [When will the DVD logo hit the corner?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251708/when-will-the-dvd-logo-hit-the-corner)

Answer (score 7):

## [Numbers vs. Strings: Language fitness challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/252057/78410)

Comment: The thing is, lenguage is quite easy to golf down due to how its encoding works and it'd require a lot of diligence to create one that's almost certainly optimal. The longer you make a solution, the more potential there is for it to be smaller.

Comment: May I take input as a list of characters for the string task?

Comment: @alephalpha Yes.

Comment: One concern I have about the string task is that it seems relatively easy in a language like BQN, which treats strings as arrays of characters and is good at manipulating arrays. I wouldn't think of BQN as being a good language for string-handling, though. Maybe the string task should involve more of the standard string-manipulation builtins like case conversion, search-and-replace, etc.

Comment: @DLosc I changed the string task to one that involves string replacement. Does it look better?

Comment: @pxeger "Given a nonempty string s consisting of uppercase letters..."

Comment: @Bubbler Wow, I'm not good at reading.

Answer (score 6):

#### PETSCII banner

[image: PETSCII on CodGolf.StackExchange]

In an other world... I was using a [PET 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_International) who used some particular [PETSCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII) charset.

The screen green on black, with 40 columns and 25 lines, was only able to display characters from this charset. No way to draw dots or lines...

But in the chaset, there is some `▝` and `▚`, which, ( by the use of *reverse video* in order to obtain 16 chars: `' ','▖','▗','▘','▝','▀','▄','▐','▌','▞','▚','▟','▛','▜','▙','█'` ) make us able to draw *graphics* on a `80x50` dots plan.

Using an internal clock triggering *IRQ*, I've done a *animated prompter* like this:

[image: Animated display sample Hello world!]

The goal of this is to make a similar banner, with same charset, (but using *UTF-8* characters: `' ','▖','▗','▘','▝','▀','▄','▐','▌','▞','▚','▟','▛','▜','▙','█'`). Warn, this charset use inverted lower/upper cases.

- This imply the use of *PETSCII* charset, I will post them there as a *json string*, before getting this out of the sandbox if some interest...
- The tool have to change his position 20 time per second.
- The tool must accept as argument, the string to display.
- The tool must add date and time in the form `- WDay MDay Mnth Year, HH:MM:SS -`
- Scrolling have to be done **bit per bit**: I.E.: by half character!
- Shortest code...

  - -3 if size of console is not limited to 40 columns
  - -5 if cpu usage stay less than 90% (On my poor Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz, with 4G ram)
  - -5+ if cpu usage stay less than 50%
  - -5+ if cpu usage stay under 5%

C.U.

Comment: as for the CPU bonuses - what is the target environment, what is the smoothing factor, and what processes count against this measure?

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score 6):

## Do-nothing Polyglot

This challenge requires you to write a polyglot which contains a comment in as many languages as possible.

The comment must say `This is a polyglot comment`.

The program must do nothing at all.

Besides comments, your code may contain no-ops from the language(s) you are using, if it helps incorporate more languages into your answers.  For example in `bash` we could use `:`.  Or in the [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) family, something like the following may be used, as long as it compiles:

```
if (0) {
    statements with side effects
}
```

Since this is a [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) challenge, the answer with the most languages wins, so I think this should also be tagged [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I think it is funny that the content of the comment makes it so that `H9+` cannot be included. Yes, tag it [code-challenge].

Comment: Many languages use `#` or `//` to signify comments. Perhaps restricting the counting so that each type of comment is counted only once. In other words, `//This is a polyglot comment` would only count for 1 language, not fo `C, C++, Java, ...`

Comment: What is a "*program*" for the purposes of this question? In particular, are compiled languages going to be excluded because the compiler won't be able to find an entry point?

Comment: What does no-ops mean?

Comment: I think that in some esolangs it's not entirely decided what counts as a comment. Maybe you should say that the code must *contain* the text `this is a polyglot comment`.

Comment: Thanks! Posting this (after I edit it)

Comment: Yeah I removed the post as it was horrible and not well recived

Answer (score 6):

## The Secret Handshake

This is based off of this [sandbox comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment10392_2440).

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

This is a challenge of secrecy.

The goal of this KOTH is to write a program that is capable of identifying itself amongst a crowd of other programs.  In order to do this, you must develop a secret handshake which will be recognized only by other copies of the same program.

A single game involves every program competing at once.  There will be five instances of each program in the arena, and the winner will be the first program to correctly identify the four other copies.  After a large number of games, the submission with the most victories will be the overall winner.

### The Gameflow:

1. Each program receives a number which tells the number of bots in the arena, which is five times the number of submissions.  The bots are arranged in a circle, and they are each considered ID #0 from their own perspective, with N-1 being the maximum ID number.
2. Then the game cycle starts.  At this point, each bot will be awaiting input.

   1. Your bot will receive input consisting of an ID number and an optional message.

      - For example, `7 hi` means that bot #7 said `hi` to you.
      - If the ID number is 0, then there will not be a message.  This would occur if it is your turn but there is no message to receive.
   2. Now, your bot is allowed to output a guess consisting of four ID numbers.

      - If those four numbers are the IDs of your teammates, then your team will win that game.
      - You will receive no confirmation of an incorrect guess.
   3. Next, you must output a message to send.  The message will be a destination ID number followed by up to 3* characters.  Example messages: `7` `4 w` `12 #?Q`.

*This number is subject to change.  Larger messages make it harder to fake a secret handshake.  I hope that a very short message forces people to use multi-step handshakes.  It might also be interesting to limit it to 1-character messages.

## Sandbox Notes

Something that I haven't quite figured out is how the controller program will determine which bot gets to move each turn.  I suppose it would be simplest go in order: Each bot has an "unread message queue" and receives/sends one message each turn.  The bot immediately after you (ID #1) then moves next.

Alternatively, there could be a set turn order which is unrelated to the ID order, simply to make it impossible for one bot to tell which bot moves next.

Comment: 1. I don't think it needs a turn order: the only problem with adding simultaneous moves would be the need to account for ties. (You are going to run it more than once to pick a winner, right?) 2. I would keep the guess per turn without penalty for guessing wrong. A good strategy will allow a team to win before anyone wins by blind guessing. Too harsh a penalty for bad guesses will bias the game too much in favour of the last person to update their bot so that it fakes the responses of other teams.

Comment: The idea is quite amusing, but something tells me there must exist a not too hard to find optimal strategy to maximize the chances of winning. The fight would likely occur around sending fake messages to the competitors. Second problem I see is, the first contestants will be at a huge disadvantage since the new players will see exactly how their code works. So much for secrecy. I think the challenge would be more interesting if the code was kept secret, but this is hardly compatible with the spirit of this site.

Comment: @PhiNotPi are you still interested in this challenge? Would you be willing to allow me to implement this?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Sure, you can implement this.  I don't think I ever started on a controller for it, mainly because I don't think this challenge will be as fun in practice as in theory.

Answer (score 6):

## You say goodbye, and I say hello

In this challenge, you have to make a program that outputs `Hello, World!`. That's not all though! When the program is reversed, it has to output `Goodbye, World!`.

Unfortunately, there are a few boring rules:

- No using comments, i.e., the Python code `print"Hello, World!"#"!dlroW ,eybdooG"tnirp` is illegal

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to do it in the least number of bytes.

(Should the forwards/backwards tasks be changed? I think they are probably too easy. Let me know if you have any suggestions.)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome)

Comment: You're missing a golden opportunity to make a [Beatles reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_Goodbye)

Comment: This is a good point. Typically in good palindrome challenges at least comments should be banned;  you can take a look at [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/heterograms-palindromes-oh-my) for some examples of good rules in a palindrome challenge.

Comment: @quartata Thank you for the example! This is what the sandbox is good for.

Comment: `Your answer may...`? :)

Comment: Do you think I can just go ahead and post this as a challenge?

Comment: What counts as a comment? Unexecuted code? Strings which are pushed and never used? etc etc

Comment: I don't think it's too easy. Easy questions get lots of answers and therefore plenty of upvotes for you.  That said, there's probably a duplicate or near duplicate out there somewhere.

Comment: it makes lots of language impossible. Maybe comment have penalty

Answer (score 6):

## What shape is that polygon?

Given an ASCII figure made of `/`, `\`, `|`, and `_`, write a program that determines (1) if the figure is a closed, non-self-intersecting polygon (meaning it has at least three sides that connect to form a loop), and if so, (2) how many sides the polygon has and (3) if the polygon is convex (all internal angles are less than 180˚) or concave (not convex, note that no polygons have 180˚ angles).

The multiline input is the ASCII figure. It can be assumed that the input only contains the four characters listed above.

If the figure is not closed or self-intersects (or has more than 2 sides connecting at the same point), the program should print `Not a polygon`.

The number of sides the polygon has is determined by the following chart.

```
Sides   Name
3       Triangle
4       Quadrilateral
5       Pentagon
6       Hexagon
7       Heptagon
8       Octagon
9       Nonagon
10      Decagon
11      Undecagon
12      Dodecagon
>12     n-gon (where n is the number of sides)
```

The output should be in the format `<concavity> <polygon name>` if (1) is satisfied.

Test cases

```
  __
 /  \__
/_____/

==> Concave hexagon


/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|____________/

==> Concave 17-gon


 _____/
|_____|

==> Not a polygon


 _
/ \
| |
\_/

==> Convex octagon
```

I need a little assistance on getting stricter definitions of points intersecting, so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I like the concept of this challenge.  A good test case would be including a line that goes inside the polygon as well as lines that doesn't even touch the polygon (unless you are going to guarantee that they will touch)

Comment: Your first two examples look wrong: those polygons are clearly concave.

Answer (score 6):

## Capsa, a card game KotH!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

Capsa, known by many times, including the name [Big Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Two) in English, is a popular card game in East Asia and South East Asia, especially throughout China, Hong Kong, Indonesia, Macau, Malaysia, Singapore and Taiwan. There are many variations and house rules. The rules of this particular variation are thus:

- This game will be played between exactly four bots. The cards are dealt between everyone, so that everyone has 13 cards.
- Rank is ordered with 2s before As as follows: 2, A, K, Q, J, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, hence, the name *Big Two*.
- Suits are ordered as follows: Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds
- Ordering runs rank first then suit. Thus, 7 of Hearts > 7 of Diamonds > 6 of Hearts, the lowest card is the 3 of Diamonds, and the highest, the 2 of Spades

You can play cards in sets of one, two or five cards, (singles, pairs, or five-card poker hands). Each set must always be bigger than the one before.

With singles, play may proceed in this way: `1 3H, 2 4H, 3 5D, 4 5C, 1 10S, 2 Pass, 3 JD, 4 Pass, 1 2S, 3 Pass`

Pairs are ordered by the higher suit in the pair. `6C6H` is of a lower rank than `6D6S`. Play may proceed in this way: `3 3D3C, 4 6D6H, 1 6D6S, 2 JHJS, 3 Pass, 4 ADAC, 1 Pass, 2 Pass`

Poker hands are ordered in the following way, from lowest in rank to highest in rank:

- Straight: Five cards that are consecutive in rank, e.g. `6H 7S 8D 9H 10C` or `JS QH KD AS 2C`. Rank is determined by the highest card, with suit used as a tie-breaker.
- Flush: Five cards with the same suit, e.g. `5H 7H 10H QH AH` Rank is determined first by suit, then by highest card.
- Full house: A three of a kind with a two of a kind, e.g. `JD JS JH 3D 3S`. Rank is determined by the triple, without regard for the pair.
- Straight flush: Five cards that are consecutive in rank and are all of the same suit, e.g. `6H 7H 8H 9H 10H`. Ranked the same as straights, with suit as a tie-breaker
- Four-of-a-kind: Four cards of the same rank, with any 5th card, e.g. `9D 9C 9H 9S 4S` This hand is known as the bomb. Wins any round of poker hands it is played in, unless someone else plays their own bomb.

Any five-card hand that is higher than the previous five-card hand played is eligible. For example, you can play a full house on a straight.

Rules of play:

- At the beginning of the game, the cards are dealt between everyone, so that everyone has 13 cards. The first player is the one that holds the 3 of Diamonds and they must play this card first, whether singly, with another 3 in a pair, or in a poker hand.
- A round begins with the first player playing a single card, a pair or a poker hand. Every other player either respond with the same number of cards (you must play singles on singles, never a pair or a poker hand), or that player passes for that round.
- A player may pass even when they have a playable card, but they must pass if none of their cards are high enough in rank, that is, if they have no playable cards. For example, in a round of poker hands, if you only have a flush as a five-card set, but another player has already played a full house, you must pass, as your flush is too low.
- The round ends when all but one player passes. That last player wins the round and starts the next round.
- The game ends when one player has played all of their cards.

Possible scoring systems:

- Bots are judged by the number of games they win over (TBD) games that they play. So if we have seven bots to test, we'll play them until every bot has played more than (TBD) games.
- Bots are judged by the number of cards they have left at the end of the game. (The winner will obviously have 0 cards at the end of the game).

[Here is the link to a preliminary controller and two bots to test against](https://github.com/Sherlock9/Capsa-KotH).

Comment: "*The cards are dealt between everyone, so that everyone has 13 cards*" belongs in the "rules of play" section, even if that means having to repeat it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Done. If you have any comments on the controller linked at the bottom of this post, I'd love to hear them. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

## Let's Play Unikong

In honor of April Fool's day, we shall have an epic battle to see who can play [Unikong](http://mgnconflict.co/unikong) best. Or, rather, whose program can play it best.

### Goal

Write a program in any language to play the game Unikong. It should seek to try and score as high as possible.

### Scoring

Whomever's program has the highest average score, over 10 games wins.

### Rules

Standard rules apply. Additionally, your program must actually play the game, not change the score variable by some other means, and you can read the variables from the game to avoid trolls and downvotes, but not modify any variables to make it easier. I will run the tests myself and will use the first 10 runs to calculate the score. Please include any specific instructions needed to run your program.

**Notes:** This would be my first question, so hopefully I got the format right. Are the rules clear enough? Do I need to clarify anything?

Comment: Do not require a video, run the programs __yourself__ and see how far they get *without* your input. No pressing continue.

Comment: Uh, will that link exist beyond today? If not then I think you'd need to find a way to replicate it (not sure about copyright here...). Anyway, I'm not really sure what counts as cheating. I think it will be hard to ban everything that's bad, so it might be better to write a controller that only allows looking at certain variables and only allows the basic player input.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I've changed the link to something that will remain after April Fool's.

Answer (score 6):

### Reverse the lengths

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

---

### Specification

In this challenge, your task is to reverse the lengths of an array-of-arrays, while keeping its concatenation intact.

More explicitly, your input is an array of arrays of nonnegative integers, which you may assume to fit in the native `int` type of your language.
The input may be an empty array or an array of empty arrays, or it may contain arrays of different lengths.
You can take the input in any reasonable format.

Your output shall be another array of arrays, again in any reasonable format.
The concatenation of the output shall be equal to the concatenation of the input, so it contains the same integers in the same order.
However, the sequence of lengths in the output shall be the *reverse* of that of the input.

### Example

Consider the input array

```
A = [[4,10],[0],[],[3,3,2],[1]]
```

The concatenation of `A` is

```
B = [4,10,0,3,3,2,1]
```

and its length sequence is

```
C = [2,1,0,3,1]
```

The correct output is

```
[[4],[10,0,3],[],[3],[2,1]]
```

since it's the unique array with concatenation `B` and length sequence `reverse(C)`.

### Rules and scoring

You con write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

### Test cases

**TODO: make more**

```
[] -> []
[[]] -> [[]]
[[],[],[1]] -> [[1],[],[]]
[[1,2],[4,5,6]] -> [[1,2,4],[5,6]]
[[4,10],[0],[],[3,3,2],[1]] -> [[4],[10,0,3],[],[3],[2,1]]
```

---

### Sandbox comments

I'm debating whether I should guarantee that the input is non-empty, and/or only contains non-empty arrays.
In some languages (like J), empty arrays make the challenge significantly harder, but on the other hand, I don't want it to be *too* easy either.

Comment: Just an FYI "reshape" operations pretty [heavily trivialise](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RuG5geG5mg&input=&args=W1s0LDEwXSxbMF0sW10sWzMsMywyXSxbMV1d) this. I don't think it would be crazy to ban them, but it's probably fine with them also.

Comment: I'd prefer the more general challenge of splitting an array the same way as another array of arrays with equally many elements.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'd prefer not to explicitly ban any builtins. If that leads to 3-byte Jelly answers, so be it. :P I also suspect Jelly would win anyway...

Comment: @xnor That would be essentially be [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43018/unflatten-an-array?rq=1), but with only arrays-of-arrays. Do you think they would be different enough not to be duplicates?

Comment: Even if the depth is fixed at 2, the shortest approach would most  likely still be the be the same in many languages. It's a borderline dupe, and since it takes only one gold badge user to close a duplicate, it will probably end up closed.

Comment: @Zgarb I'm not sure if I'd count it as a dupe, but I think reversed input vs general array wouldn't make much difference there. I expect most solutions would just work with the reversed input as if it were a general array.

Comment: @xnor Reversed input has the added complexity that the same array must be used for content and shape. That's not a big problem for some languages, but I'd expect another approach to outgolf the pop/map approach with the added overhead of creating a second reference for the reversed array in, e.g., Python. I admit I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: I think what you call "concatenation" of the array is called "flattening".

Answer (score 6):

## Implement Brainfuck Algorithms

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

In order to make [algorithms written in brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) more understandable, you can write them in a more abstract notation, where you give a given cell a name, and instead of lots of unreadable `<` and `>` instructions to move the pointer to a specific, you just write down the name of the cell. Let us see an example:

This algorithm doubles the value in cell `x`, and saves the result again in `x`. It needs an additional temporary cells `t`

```
t[-]          clear temporary variable
x[t+x-]       move the value from x to t
t[x++t-]      move twice as many units from t back to x
```

Now lets see what this would look like, if `x` was the cell with index `0`, and `t` was the cell with index `2`, assuming the poninter is in position `0` when the algorithm starts:

```
>>[-] 
<<[>>+<<-]  
>>[<<++>>-]
```

#### Challenge

Given a string with a valid (see below) *brainfuck algorithm*, a list of strings containing the cell names and a list of integers containing the indices of each of the cell of the previous list, your program/function has to return an implementation of this algorithm in brainfuck.

#### Details

- The pointer is assumed to be on a cell with index `0` when the implementation is executed.
- The two given lists can also be in a different reasonable format e.g. `[cell1,index1,cell2,index2,...]` or `[[cell1,index1],[cell2,index2],...` or as arguments of a function with a variable number of arguments etc.
- You can assume that in the given string representing the algorithm, there are only brainfuck instructions as well as cell names, but no other symbols (no line breaks, no spaces)
- The cell names consist of lower- and uppercase characters `A-Z` and `a-z` as well as digits `0-9`
- The cell names in the string are always separated by at least one BF instruction symbol.
- You can assume that the pointer is the same index whenever it enters a loop as it exits the same loop.

#### Examples

#### [x=y](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#x_.3D_y):

```
String (remove line breaks):
  temp0[-]
  x[-]
  y[x+temp0+y-]
  temp0[y+temp0-]
List of variable names: [temp0,x,y]
List of indices:        [    2,0,1]
Output (remove line breaks):
  >>[-]
  <<[-]
  >[<+>>+<-]
  >>[<+>-]
```

#### [x=x*x](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#x_.3D_x_.2A_x)

```
String (
  temp0[-]
  temp1[-]
  temp2[-]
  x[temp2+temp1+x-]
  temp1[
    temp2[x+temp0+temp2-]
    temp0[temp2+temp0-]
    temp1-
  ]
List of variable names: [x,temp0,temp1,temp2]
List of indices:        [0,    1,    2,    3]
Output (remove line breaks):
  >[-]
  >[-]
  >[-]
  <<<[>>>+<+<<-]
   >>[
    >[<<+>+>>-]
    <<[>>+<<-]
    >-
  ]
```

(More to be added)

Comment: Aah, I just noticed something when writeing that line (see meta section) but I do not have time right now to think through that. That's why this part was unfinished.

Comment: I think that this is undecidable. Consider a line of the form `x[algorithm]` where `algorithm` doesn't guarantee to leave the pointer where it started. For the subsequent line to move the pointer to the desired cell it needs to know whether `x` was zero going into that line or not.

Comment: I think the problem can be solved by requiring that there are no `<>` in the input. Although that would make the resulting language not Turing-complete (can only access finite amount of memory)

Answer (score 6):

## Solve the Nonogram!

It is time to embark on a perilous quest to defeat the British Intelligence. The aim of this challenge is to write the shortest code that will solve a Nonogram.

## What is a Nonogram?

[image: Nonogram Puzzle]

> The rules are simple. 
>   You have a grid of squares, which must be either filled in black or left blank. Beside each row of the grid are listed the lengths of the runs of black squares on that row. Above each column are listed the lengths of the runs of black squares in that column. Your aim is to find all black squares. In this puzzle type, the numbers are a form of discrete tomography that measures how many unbroken lines of filled-in squares there are in any given row or column. For example, a clue of "4 8 3" would mean there are sets of four, eight, and three filled squares, in that order, with at least one blank square between successive groups.
>    [[1](http://www.puzzle-nonograms.com)][[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram)]

So the solution to the above Nonogram would be:

[image: Solved nonogram]

## Implementation Details

You can chose to represent the Nonogram however you would like and take it as an input in whatever way you deem fit for your language. Same goes for output. The aim of this challenge is to literally just get the job done; if you can solve the monogram with whatever output your program gives, that is valid. One caveat is you can't use an online solver :)

You are, of course, free to use any language you want and since this is code golf, the entries will be sorted in the order: `accuracy -> length of code -> speed.`

This problem is very algorithmically challenging in that there is no completely efficient solution to it and as such, you won't be penalized for not being able to solve larger ones, although your answer will be heavily rewarded if it is able to handle big cases (see bonus). As a benchmark, my solution works for up to roughly  50x50 within 5-10 mins.

## Bonus

I actually learnt about Nonograms from a cryptographic Christmas card released by the British Intelligence [here](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news-article/christmas-card-cryptographic-twist-charity). The first part was basically a massive 25x25 Nonogram. If your solution is able to solve this, you will get kudos :)

To make your life easier in terms of data entry, I have provided how I represented the data for this specific puzzle for your free use. The first 25 lines are the row clues, followed by a '-' separator line, followed by 25 lines of the col clues, followed by a '#' separator line, and then a representation of the grid with the square clues filled in.

```
7 3 1 1 7
1 1 2 2 1 1
1 3 1 3 1 1 3 1
1 3 1 1 6 1 3 1
1 3 1 5 2 1 3 1
1 1 2 1 1
7 1 1 1 1 1 7
3 3
1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 2
1 1 3 2 1 1
4 1 4 2 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 4 1 3
2 1 1 1 2 5
3 2 2 6 3 1
1 9 1 1 2 1
2 1 2 2 3 1
3 1 1 1 1 5 1
1 2 2 5
7 1 2 1 1 1 3
1 1 2 1 2 2 1
1 3 1 4 5 1
1 3 1 3 10 2
1 3 1 1 6 6
1 1 2 1 1 2
7 2 1 2 5
-
7 2 1 1 7
1 1 2 2 1 1
1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1
1 3 1 1 5 1 3 1
1 3 1 1 4 1 3 1
1 1 1 2 1 1
7 1 1 1 1 1 7
1 1 3
2 1 2 1 8 2 1
2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2
1 7 3 2 1
1 2 3 1 1 1 1 1
4 1 1 2 6
3 3 1 1 1 3 1
1 2 5 2 2
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
1 3 3 2 1 8 1
6 2 1
7 1 4 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 4
1 3 1 3 7 1
1 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 4
1 3 1 4 3 3
1 1 2 2 2 6 1
7 1 3 2 1 1
#
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I love these puzzles! I definitely support this question.

Comment: @DanTheMan http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/can-you-beat-the-british-intelligence-nonogram-solver/91750#91750 :D

Answer (score 6):

## There can be only `1`!

Your task is, given a positive integer `n`, to generate an expression that equals to the number `n`.

The catch is: you're only allowed the number `1` in the output.

The operators at your disposal are:

- `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`
- `sqrt` (as `s`)
- `ceil` and `floor` (as `c` and `f` respectively)
- `!` (factorial)

  - The factorial, in this case, only works for positive integers.

You are also allowed to stack `1`'s together, so something like `11` is acceptable in the output. However, they count as the same amount of `1`'s that's in the number (so `11` counts as 2 `1`'s).

You must also include brackets in the output, so that the expression in the output, when executed through the order of operations, will result in the input.

### Examples:

- Input = 24, one possible output = `(1+1+1+1)!`
- Input = 11, one possible output = `11`
- Input = 5, one possible output = `c(s((1+1+1+1)!))`

  - The ceiling of the square root of `24` is `5`.

### Rules:

- You are guaranteed that the input is a positive integer from `1` to `2^31-1`.
- Your program must work for any positive integer up to `2^31-1`, even if they are not tested.
- Your program must finish processing all outputs for all numbers in the set in 1 hour.
- The results for every run of the program must be exactly the same - also, no seeds.
- You are not allowed to have imaginary numbers anywhere in the output (so no `s(some negative number)`).
- You are also not allowed to have numbers larger than `2^31-1` anywhere in the output, even when they are `sqrt`ed or `/`ed (so no `(((1+1+1)!)!)!` or `((1+1+1+1)!)!`).

### Set of Numbers:

```
945536, 16878234, 32608778, 42017515, 48950830, 51483452, 52970263, 54278649, 63636656, 78817406, 89918907, 90757642, 95364861, 102706605, 113965374, 122448605, 126594161, 148064959, 150735075, 154382918, 172057472, 192280850, 194713795, 207721209, 220946392, 225230299, 227043979, 241011012, 248906099, 249796314, 250546528, 258452706, 276862988, 277140688, 280158490, 286074562, 308946627, 310972897, 322612091, 324445400, 336060042, 346729632, 349428326, 352769482, 363039453, 363851029, 392168304, 401975104, 407890409, 407971913, 425780757, 459441559, 465592122, 475898732, 482826596, 484263150, 506235403, 548951531, 554295842, 580536366, 587051904, 588265985, 588298051, 590968352, 601194306, 607771869, 618578932, 626776380, 667919873, 681786366, 689854904, 692055400, 697665495, 711608194, 734027104, 750869335, 757710567, 759967747, 777616154, 830071127, 833809927, 835873060, 836438554, 836945593, 863728236, 864158514, 871273503, 881615667, 891619600, 897181691, 918159061, 920521050, 924502226, 929983535, 943162304, 950210939, 950214176, 962610357, 974842859, 988572832
```

(These are 100 random numbers from 1 to 1 billion.)

### Scoring System:

Your score is determined like so:

- Your program will be tested against the random numbers in the set.

  - You must provide the output generated using the numbers random numbers in the set (either inside your answer or as a pastebin link).
- Your then have two "scores": A primary score and a secondary score.

  - Your primary score is `(no. of 1's in output)*(no. of operators in output)`. If your primary score is the lowest, you win.
  - Your secondary score is your byte-count, and is only used in the case of a tie-breaker - the person with the lowest byte-count wins.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)

### Meta:

- Anything that I need to clear up?
- Is this challenge a dupe?

Comment: Is implicit multiplication allowed?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 No, it is not allowed. You must use `*`.

Comment: For the tiebreak, do parentheses contribute to the operator count?

Comment: Does the code need to be deterministic (that is, do random algorithms need to set the PRNG seed to ensure the same results each time)?

Comment: Surely at least **one** output must be hardcoded?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58084/42545), though I don't believe it's a dupe.

Comment: [tag:code-challenge] can't be used along with other scoring tags.

Answer (score 6):

## Telegraphy Golf: Decode Baudot Code

### Background

In 1870 Émile Baudot invented [Baudot Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code), a fixed-length character
encoding for telegraphy. He designed the code to be entered from a
manual keyboard with just five keys; two operated with the left hand and
three with the right:

[image: Baudot 5-key keyboard]

The right index, middle and ring fingers operate the *I*, *II*, and
*III* keys, respectively, and the left index and middle fingers operate
*IV* and *Ⅴ*. (Henceforth I'll use their Western Arabic numerals, i.e.
*1*, through *5*.) Characters are entered as chords. To enter the letter
"C," for example, the operator presses the *1*, *3*, and *4* keys
simultaneously, whereupon a rotating brush arm reads each key in
sequence and transmits a current or, for keys not depressed, no current.
The result is, in modern terms, a 5-bit least-significant-bit-first
binary encoding, in which our example, "C," is encoded as `10110`.

#### 5 bits??

You might be thinking that 5 bits, which can express at most 32 unique
symbols, isn't enough for even all of the English letters and numerals,
to say nothing of punctuation. Baudot had a trick up his sleeve, though:
His character set is actually *two* distinct sets: *Letters* and
*Figures*, and he defined two special codes to switch between them.
*Letter Shift*, which switches to Letters mode, is activated by pressing
the *5* key alone (`00001`), and *Figure Shift* is activated with the
*4* key (`00010`).

### Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program or function that decodes Baudot
Code transmissions.

A real transmission would begin with some initialization bits, plus a
start and stop bit before and after each character, but we're going to
skip those and only worry about the 5 unique bits for each character.
Input and output formats are discussed below.

#### Baudot's Code

There are two different versions of Baudot Code: Continental and U.K.
We're going use the U.K. version, which *doesn't* include characters
like "É" from Baudot's native French. We're also going to leave out all
of the symbols in the U.K. version that aren't among the printable ASCII
characters. You will only have to decode the characters in the table
below, all of which are printable ASCII characters except the final three control
characters that are explained below the table.

The "Ltr" column shows the characters in Letter mode and "Fig" shows the
Figure mode characters:

```
        Encoding             Encoding
Ltr Fig  12345       Ltr Fig  12345
--- --- --------     --- --- --------
 A   1   10000        P   +   11111
 B   8   00110        Q   /   10111
 C   9   10110        R   -   00111
 D   0   11110        S       00101
 E   2   01000        T       10101
 F       01110        U   4   10100
 G   7   01010        V   '   11101
 H       11010        W   ?   01101
 I       01100        X       01001
 J   6   10010        Y   3   00100
 K   (   10011        Z   :   11001
 L   =   11011        -   .   10001
 M   )   01011        ER  ER  00011
 N       01111        SP  FS  00010
 O   5   11100        LS  SP  00001
 /       11000
```

The last three rows in the right column are control characters:

- **`ER`** is *Erasure*. Baudot's telegraphy machines would print an
  asterisk-like symbol for this character to tell the reader that the
  preceding character should be ignored, but we're going to be even
  nicer to the reader and *actually omit (do not print) the preceding
  character*. It acts the same in both Letter and Figure mode.
- **`FS`** is *Figure Shift*. This switches the character set from
  Letters to Figures. If the decoder is *already* in Figure mode,
  FS is treated as a *Space* (ergo `SP` in the "Ltr" column). When the decoder is in Figure mode it stays in Figure mode until an LS character is received.
- **`LS`** is *Letter Shift*. It switches the character set from
  Figures to Letters. If the decoder is already in Letter mode, LS is treated as a *Space*. When in Letter mode the decoder stays in Letter mode until an FS character is received.

The decoder always starts in Letter mode.

Here's an example with Figure Shift, Letter Shift, and Space:

```
01011 10000 00100 00001 00010 10000 11100 00001 10101 11010
  M     A     Y   LS/SP FS/SP   1     5   LS/SP   T     H
```

This yields the message `MAY 15TH`. As you can see, the first `00001` (Letter Shift/Space) character acts as a space, because the decoder is already in Letter mode. The next character, `00010` (Figure Shift/Space) switches the decoder to Figure mode to print `15`. Then `00001` appears again, but this time it acts as Letter Shift to put the decoder back in Letter mode.

For your convenience, here are the characters in a format that's perhaps
easier to digest in an editor, sorted by code:

```
A,1,10000|E,2,01000|/,,11000|Y,3,00100|U,4,10100|I,,01100|O,5,11100|SP,FS,00010|J,6,10010|G,7,01010|H,,11010|B,8,00110|C,9,10110|F,,01110|D,0,11110|LS,SP,00001|-,.,10001|X,,01001|Z,:,11001|S,,00101|T,,10101|W,?,01101|V,',11101|ER,ER,00011|K,(,10011|M,),01011|L,=,11011|R,-,00111|Q,/,10111|N,,01111|P,+,11111
```

#### Input

Input will be a string, array, or list of bits in
least-significant-bit-first order. Each character will be represented
by a quintet of 5 bits. Bits may be in any reasonable format, e.g. a
binary string, an array of `0`s and `1`s, a string of `"0"` and `"1"`
characters, a single very large number, etc., as long as it maps
directly to the bits of the transmission.

Every transmission will have at least one printable quintet and at most
255 quintets (printable or otherwise), i.e. 5–1,275 bits inclusive.

The input can contain *only* the bits of the transmission, with two
allowed exceptions: Any number of leading or trailing `0` bits and/or,
for string input, a single trailing newline may be added to the
transmission. Leading or trailing bits or characters *cannot* be added
before or after each quintet, i.e. you cannot pad each quintet to 8 bits
or separate quintets with any additional bits, e.g. `"01111\n11100"`.

Notes & edge cases

1. The transmission will contain only the characters in the "Ltr" and
   "Fig" columns in the table above. You will never receive e.g.
   `01110` in Figure mode, because it is absent from the "Fig" column.
2. It is assumed that the decoder will always be in Letter mode at the
   beginning of a transmission. However, the first character *may* be an
   FS character to switch to Figure mode immediately.
3. When the decoder is in Letter mode, it may receive an LS character, and when it is in Figure mode it may receive an FS character. In either event a Space character must be printed (see Output).
4. The ER character will never be the first character in a transmission, nor will it ever immediately follow an LS, FS, or another ER.
5. An FS character may immediately follow an LS character and vice versa.
6. Neither the LS nor FS character will be the last character in any transmission.
7. The `/` and `-` characters may be received in either Letter mode
   (codes `11000` and `10001`, respectively) or Figure mode (`10111`
   and `00111`).

#### Output

Output may be in any reasonable format, the most reasonable being ASCII
(or UTF-8, for which all of the represented characters are the same as
ASCII). Please indicate in your answer if your output is in another
encoding or format.

Notes

- The space character (see 3. above) should be an ASCII space (0x20)
  or your encoding's equivalent, i.e. what you get when you press the
  space bar.

### Winning

This is code golf. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Restrictions

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Trailing spaces and/or a single trailing newline are allowed. Leading spaces or other characters (that are not part of the transmission) are disallowed.
- You may not use any built-in or library functions that decode Baudot Code (or any of its descendants, e.g. Murray Code, ITA-1, etc.).

### Test Cases

```
Input: 001101000010100111101110010101
Output: BAUDOT
```

```
Input: 11010010001001100011110111101111100
Output: HELLO
```

```
Input: 01011100000010000001000101000011100000011010111010
Output: MAY 15TH
```

```
Input: 00010001000001000001011101110011100101010010110101010001111100101
Output: 32 FOOTSTEPS
```

```
Input: 10110000110101011100111100001111011010000001101110
Output: GOLF
```

```
Input: 000100011000001111100000100010110111001100010110010000111111
Output: 8D =( :P
```

```
Input: 0000100001000010000100010001111011111011000011100010001
Output (4 leading spaces):     -/=/-
```

Comment: This is quite similar to the Morse decoding question. The main thing it adds is the three control characters. It might be worth adding a cross-reference in a comment after posting the question.

Comment: Can the transmission start with erasure?

Comment: @Sp3000 No. Good catch. I had a note to that effect but apparently accidentally deleted it.

Comment: Can an erasure follow a shift that is acting as a space?

Comment: @Phlarx Nope.  ER will never follow LS or FS.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, all. I've posted the challenge: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94056/telegraphy-golf-decode-baudot-code

Comment: Don't forget to take of this answer in the Sandbox. *" When you think your challenge is ready for the public, go ahead and post it, **replace the post here with a link to the challenge and delete it.** "*

Answer (score 6):

*my first post on here, be gentle ;)*

---

## Find all anagrams within a text

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Somehow I stumbled upon an implementation of a school assignment from about a year ago, and after having seen many amazing and mindblowing code-golf solutions on here, I thought it's time I bring my own challenge and see how much you guys can blow my mind again ;)

### The assignment

Given a text, find all words that have at least one other word in the text as an anagram (case insensitive). Multiple occurrences of the same word are **not** counted.

The output shall be grouped by words that are an anagram of each other.

### Rules

- How you handle input/output is up to you. Function-parameters, file-io, standard in/out, whatever works the best for you.
- You must be able handle any non-empty input as long as you don't run into language or memory limitations.
- The output does not have any fixed formatting. That means you may put them each group at a line, or put them all at one line but use different delimiters, a 2d array, some other exotic data-structure your language of choice happens to have, as long as it makes reasonable sense, it is considered correct. (This means that for example if you are just writing a function, that function does not need to display the output, it could just provide it as a return-value.) Just keep in mind the requirement that the words that are an anagram of each other should be grouped together.
- The order in which the output appears does not matter. That applies to the order of the groups as well as the order of the words within the group.
- A group of only one word is invalid, since that fails the "have at least one other word in the text as an anagram" requirement. (just omit them from your output ^^)
- Each word should only appear once in the output
- All interpunction characters are stripped away from the word before checking for anagrams. That means that "it's" and "its" are the same word (and thus both are an anagram of "sit"). My sample program at the bottom uses http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct as check if a character is an interpuntion character. If your language has such a method, you may use it. Otherwise take the characters from the default C locale as specified on there:

  > `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``
- All other characters are part of the word and treated as is, so "a" and "á" are not the same.

### Example

Given the following input text (the actual text I was given as example by school :P, no idea where this text is coming from...)

> Parts of the world have sunlight for close to 24 hours during summer. Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer. He had a strap on his head to identify himself as the leader. Dan had to deal with the sun never going down for 42 consecutive days and his leadership strap soon became a blindfold. He wondered what kind of traps lay ahead of him.

the following output would be correct:

- 24, 42
- deal, lead
- and, dan
- parts, strap, traps

Or this would also be correct:

> 24, 42 | deal, lead | and, dan | parts, strap, traps

This one would not

> 24, 42 , deal, lead , and, dan , parts, strap, traps

(since the groups are not obvious)

### My own (non golfed) version to check

The is the exact program I submitted to school back then. You may use it to check your own results.

Added bonus: If it happens to be that this program has a bug (I haven't found them yet) your submission is allowed to have it as well, since it is used to check the result. (In that case you are of course not *required* to have said bugs)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

void stringRemoveInterpunction(std::string& string);
void stringToLower(std::string& string);
std::string stringToAnagramIdentifier(std::string word);

/**
 * due to use of std::ispunct and std::tolower it may not work for text with non-ascii characters??!
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream fileStream(argv[1]);
    if (!fileStream) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // map to store the anagrams, key is so called "anagram identifier", value is a list of the words.
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> anagrams;

    // read words separated by whitespace from the file
    for (std::string word; fileStream >> word;) {
        // remove interpunction & convert to lowercase, since casing should be ignored
        stringRemoveInterpunction(word); stringToLower(word);

        // add to anagrams-store
        anagrams[stringToAnagramIdentifier(word)].insert(word);
    }

    // display all the anagrams
    for (auto anagram : anagrams) {
        // skip entries which contains only one item, no anagrams found
        if (anagram.second.size() <= 1) {
            continue;
        }

        // output a comma-separated list of the anagrams
        auto anagramIterator = anagram.second.begin();
        std::cout << *anagramIterator++;
        while (anagramIterator != anagram.second.end()) {
            std::cout << ", " << *anagramIterator++;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void stringRemoveInterpunction(std::string& string) {
    string.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&ispunct)), string.end());
}

void stringToLower(std::string& string) {
    std::transform(string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::tolower));
}

std::string stringToAnagramIdentifier(std::string word) {
    // sort the characters
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    return word;
}
```

---

## Sandbox Questions

- Do i need to add other tags, or is just code-golf enough?
- <s>I'm not completely sure about the upper-limit of the input text. My idea was that the code should be able to handle any size input as long as its within the memory-limits of the language. Like you don't have to write "memory optimal code" or something, but also shouldn't asume it is smaller than X. I could also just pick an upper limit of "1 kilobyte" or something to avoid any uncertainty about the requirements</s> I think this is fine now as it is.
- Someone in the comments below asked how to handle special characters like $?() so I took a look at how my "check program" handled that and it strips them away before doing the anagram check. So I added a rule for that, but while writing that I felt it makes it needlessly complicated and I'm considering ditching that rule and altering my check-program to reflect that (but then I cant claim its the exact same anymore :( )
- Any other parts that are not clear?

Comment: What happens if there are 3 that are anagrams, such as `eat ate tea`? Are they all printed in one line / group?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc yes, like "parts, strap, traps" in the example

Comment: I suggest you remove the grouping rule, since it's not really the interesting part of the challenge. It just adds code and limits the solutions. It's apparent which of the words that are together anyway. I do suggest they have to be grouped though, but without the need for delimiters.

Comment: I think the memory rule is fine. I'm quite sure people will write a script that in theory would work for any input length if it wasn't for language or memory limitations. I also suggest you guarantee at least one character in the input. Otherwise people would need to add code just to handle empty input and that's not the interesting part of the challenge.

Comment: You should add rules regarding special characters. Are it's, sit and its anagrams? What about hyphens? Can there be any special characters such as $?() etc? How are they treated?

Comment: @StewieGriffin The grouping thing is a natural result of my solution to the problem back then, and imo its a fun part of the challenge, so I'm not totally sure about removing it.
About the memory limit: I'm totally fine with the guarantee of at least one character if you think empty input needs special handling (i didnt think it would, but I dont really care :P)
And yes, you are correct about special characters. I'd say "it's" is two words: "it" and "s". All special characters are ignored, so essentially regarded as whitespace between words. I'll add that

Comment: welp, turns out I handled special characters differently, I strip them away from the word, so "it's" becomes "its", guess that'll be the rule then since I want to keep as close as possible to the original program

Comment: @StewieGriffin I added a rule about special character handling, but I'm not completely sure about it, thoughts? (see my added "sandbox question")

Comment: parsing and anagrams are relevant tags, maybe strings too, but I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_{|}~` are all the non-alphanumeric ASCII-characters, except ``\` ``. I suggest you include the missing two symbols in the list to ignore, and say: "All non-alphanumeric characters (except spaces and newlines) must be trimmed away. So, `it's` and `its` are the same word." (You might want to rephrase that since my English isn't perfect, but something along those lines. If this is the rule then `R2D2` and `dr.22` will be anagrams, I'm not sure if that the desired behavior..?

Comment: PS! I don't mean to be difficult, it's just that in my experience you'll get these questions sooner or later. So it's a good thing to sort it out while it's still in the Sandbox :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin those two characters should have been included, look at the list from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct where I got it from, somehow I messed up the copy-paste :( And about "what is desired behaviour?" Im honestly not sure, I never really thought about it before you mentioned it and then I looked at how my sample program handled it. I remember putting in the ispunct-trim for stuff like commas after a word, im not sure about characters *within* the word...

Comment: You _can_ say that the input will not have any special characters except `'` and `-`. Those two must be trimmed away. I think you must include those two, since these can be found in many texts.

Answer (score 6):

## Tower Builder [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

The king is coming to visit!  Your city is competing with another neighboring city to attract his attention.

**Each player owns their own tower** within a city full of other players.  Each turn you place 1 blocks on your tower or another tower in your city.

After 100 turns, **the king will only visit the city with the highest tower.**  If he visits your city, then you will gain points equal to the number of blocks in **your personal tower**.  In the case of a tie, neither city is visited.

Games include all players, and each game will randomly arrange players into cities.  Your score is the total score across all games.

- Player identifiers are randomly generated at the start of the tournament, but are consistent from game to game.
- In addition, contrary to past KoTHs:  I allow saving state from game to game (but not between tournaments)
- You will always have complete information, including:

  - The size of everybody's towers (including the other city)
  - The actions players have taken
  - The current score of all players

Comment: How is always playing on the tallest tower in your city a bad strategy? Maybe the other city will do the same, but you won't lose.

Comment: @aschepler because the number of points you get is height of your *personal* tower.  If you only build on another's tower, and never your own, you'll never get any points.

Comment: @NathanMerrill it took me a few minutes to understand what you even meant by that. you probably need to make this more clear

Comment: If the points are only awarded to the player who is visited by the king, it would seem that putting 99 blocks on the city tower and 1 block on your personal tower guarantees victory, no?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork there's no singular "city tower".  Furthermore, you are still competing against the players in your city.  Your score is your total score across many games.

Comment: Oh, the part that I missed was that multiple players share a city. I think that should be made more clear because that will drastically change strategy. I read it as you have a personal tower and everyone also gets their own city with a separate tower, and it's only the city's tower that matters for the king.

Comment: This needs some clarification about arrangement. The game will randomly arrange players into one of () cities, or a city with () others in it

Comment: @pfg It'll definitely be one of () cities, but I'm not sure how many.  My intuition says "2", but I can't give a solid reason.  Any suggestions?

Comment: 2 or 3 per city or total cities? 3 seems good per city because with just two the strategy is much easier @Nathan Merrill

Comment: Hmmm...I'm thinking 100 players in 2 cities, and allow for duplicate entries.

Comment: It seems to me that if you allow saving state you can simplify the last point to "You will be notified of the actions of every player" and let those who want to analyse it calculate the sizes of the towers, scores, etc. Normally I would favour supplying calculated information to save the players from re-implementing the game logic, but here the logic is simpler than the serialisation would be.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I already provide complete information about the current game (including its history).  The difference here is that you are allowed to persist information from game to game, meaning you can remember players who are antagonistic.

Comment: My point is that the communication between the server and the bots would be simpler if you *didn't* provide that information, and you don't *need* to provide it because it can be calculated easily.

Answer (score 6):

## PPCG Handwriting OCR [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

(insert logo here once I make it)

Given an image consisting of handwritten text, output the text that is written. The image of the handwritten text will be generated by taking characters from one or more handwriting samples given by PPCG users.

### Rules

- You may not hardcode your program to only recognize the samples in the corpus.
- There will be sufficient spacing between characters to avoid ambiguity.
- Only ASCII alphanumeric characters (those matching the regex `[A-Za-z0-9]`, i.e. uppercase and lowercase English letters and digits) will be present in the input.
- Inputs will be formed by concatenating individual characters from the handwriting samples.
- The test cases used for scoring may be modified at any point if I feel it is necessary to do so. Reasons may include but are not limited to: needing more test cases to have a single winner, removing problematic test cases, and fixing errors in test cases.

Aside from the above considerations, there are no guarantees on the appearance of the handwriting, as these are actual handwriting samples and thus can have drastic variances.

### Score

Your score will be the number of test cases that are correctly recognized, divided by the total number of test cases. The highest score wins. In the event of a tie, the first submission to reach the high score wins. Additional test cases may be added to break ties.

### Handwriting Samples

[This Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNhb2.jpg) contains the handwriting samples, as well as the names of the users who contributed them.

---

[I've made a chat room for submitting handwriting samples](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63159/ppcg-handwriting-ocr-challenge). The more samples I get, the better this challenge will be, so please take a few minutes and submit a sample!

Comment: `You may not hardcode your program to only recognize the samples in the corpus.`: Can we tailor our code to be better for the samples than other inputs though?

Comment: `The test cases used for scoring may be modified at any point`: Will current answers be modified?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder 1) [No](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/45941). 2) Answers will be run on the test cases any time the answer or the test cases change, and the scores will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Hadn't seen that loophole before :)

Comment: Can I nitpick again and say handwriting OCR is called ICR? :P

Comment: Can you add an example input as well?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder 1) ICR is when a program tries to learn what handwriting looks like via machine learning. OCR is just parsing written/text input into data. This is OCR, not ICR. 2) I'll add some examples once I get more samples and finish writing my generator.

Comment: Can you assume a minimum height for the characters?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `Aside from the above considerations, there are no guarantees on the appearance of the handwriting, as these are actual handwriting samples and thus can have drastic variances.`

Comment: To be honest with no restrictions this is going to be very hard, Do you lose points for returning extra information? Assume the input `Hello` if I return `H.e.l.l.o.` is that 100% for that test case or do I lose and get something like 50%?

Comment: And does the output have to be in the correct order?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It's all or nothing. Getting 100% on a test battery challenge should be hard.

Comment: Please update imgur album

Comment: @Pavel I will once I finish cutting up the images. My free time has been limited these past few weeks.

Answer (score 6):

## ASCII Stock Exchange [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

At the *ASCII Stock Exchange*, each character has a price. If a character is used more often, its price rises, otherwise the price decreases over time.

Initially, each character has price 10. *[Meta: Is this too low/high?]* After each answer, the prices change as follows:

- Each character that is not used in the answer's code has its price decreased by one, except when the price is already one, in which case it stays one.
- If a character is used *n*-times, then its price increases by *n*.

We define the *score* of a piece of code as the sum of the prices of its characters.

#### Example

For the sake of simplicity, we only consider characters `A`, `B` and `C` for this example. The challenge itself works with all bytes from `\0` to `\255`. Initially, we have the following prices:

```
A -> 10, B -> 10, C -> 10
```

If the code of the first answer is `BAAA`, then is has a score of 40 (computed by taking the *previous* character prices into account) and the prices change to

```
A -> 13, B -> 11, C -> 9
```

If the next answer is `CC`, it has a score of 18 and the prices are updated to

```
A -> 12, B -> 10, C -> 11
```

### The Task

Your objective is to write a program or function which calculates the score of a given piece of code in dependence of a list of previous answers which all influence the initial prices in the way described above.

The goal is to do so while minimizing the submission's score itself in the context of this challenge, that is your submission should be able to calculate its own score by taking a list of all previous submissions and its own source code as input.

The answer with the lowest score in each language wins.

### Rules

- You may take a list of strings and a string as input, or require that the string to be scored is the first/last element of the list, or any other reasonable input format.
- You may not answer twice in a row.
- If an answer in language *X* has already been posted, you may only post another answer in language *X* if your submission achieves a lower score than the previous answer and the code is not identical.
- For this challenge only major releases of languages are considered their own language (e.g. *Java 7* vs. *Java 8*). If there already is an answer in version *A* of a language and you have an answer in version *B* of the language and are in doubt whether version *B* is different enough from version *A* to be treated as different language, make sure that your code is not valid in version *A*.

### Answer Format

To avoid having to copy all previous answers in order to calculate your submission's score, the chain will maintain a [score calculator](https://tio.run/##dVJNaxsxFLzrV8whsCtiG7uQS6gLJfTQngo52qGoa8UW2ZWEPuIa8t@372nXJGuT29PM6M2sdg4qvui27XvTeRcSHk8x6W7xw76a4GynbRIinbzG72AajTXqh4MKM/y0SQrRKWMJ2zkIACrsI77OsdfpO40MGetzGrEHZxPtK7gPxibcIDYuaNRocgjE/fHsEodNcrgtxCC6v8emhHjC/BseE23Y80RJRsV4uXE7Dhpzhw083tBwAEZnaHVC/SvHBC9J0zr3kj0JxqtPQlwkYdfBq9iOCS5Vazy7dtci@51K@owaa5JR7XgUYnr@8EGXzBqd8qi3DVvWzWy1lBKbarusFotq@@XurqKgU6/PXufsMFVPX6qYfRQUQuKce0KR0fv2oRTnQVztoPClLQWR/OPfQIVZY0kjl2mgO/UPK9TDvTlWcpS6dNDhaKJ@lw6aW9giORKveSO5ZSoUa4ox/ccCUFru63VjRj13QNt9OmCBZ9MmHVBTvEb2PRf35HKgIv3tTIzG2Wp8MnZlvvdBvxqXY69sPOoQe2b@Aw) on TIO. Click on the link to the calculator in the previous answer and enter your code into the input field to calculate its score. Then add your code as a command-line argument, generate a new link and include it in your answer for the next submission.

If you wrote answer number 42 in Haskell with a score of 100, please format it as

> ## 42. [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 100
>
> ```
>  <code>
> ```
>
> TIO-Link, explanation, ...
>
> [Score calculator for next answer](https://tio.run/##dVJNaxsxFLzrV8whsCtiG7uQS6gLJfTQngo52qGoa8UW2ZWEPuIa8t@372nXJGuT29PM6M2sdg4qvui27XvTeRcSHk8x6W7xw76a4GynbRIinbzG72AajTXqh4MKM/y0SQrRKWMJ2zkIACrsI77OsdfpO40MGetzGrEHZxPtK7gPxibcIDYuaNRocgjE/fHsEodNcrgtxCC6v8emhHjC/BseE23Y80RJRsV4uXE7Dhpzhw083tBwAEZnaHVC/SvHBC9J0zr3kj0JxqtPQlwkYdfBq9iOCS5Vazy7dtci@51K@owaa5JR7XgUYnr@8EGXzBqd8qi3DVvWzWy1lBKbarusFotq@@XurqKgU6/PXufsMFVPX6qYfRQUQuKce0KR0fv2oRTnQVztoPClLQWR/OPfQIVZY0kjl2mgO/UPK9TDvTlWcpS6dNDhaKJ@lw6aW9giORKveSO5ZSoUa4ox/ccCUFru63VjRj13QNt9OmCBZ9MmHVBTvEb2PRf35HKgIv3tTIzG2Wp8MnZlvvdBvxqXY69sPOoQe2b@Aw)

### Test Cases

These test cases are in the format `list of strings, string to score -> result`.

```
[], "BAAA" -> 40
["BAAA"], "CC" -> 18
["abc"], "abc" -> 33
["ab12", "aa22", "31a"], "ac23" -> 42
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"], "123" -> 3
```

---

### Meta

- Any idea what could be a good initial price? I picked the number 10 rather arbitrarily.
- <s>Letting the cost of unused characters decrease until 0 might lead to score 0 answers. Do you think this is a problem and the minimum cost should be 1?</s> Minimum changed to 1.
- <s>I'm unsure what range of characters is a sensible choice. Limiting answers to printable ASCII plus white space would make things easier but also exclude a lot of languages. Another possibility would be to allow the whole byte range from \0 to \255. Then also golfing languages could participate, albeit to score them they would need to be converted to their byte form which usually contains a lot of unprintable characters. The score calculator is able to handle unprintables, but I don't know how to insert them into the text fields on TIO.</s> All bytes from `\0` to '\255' are allowed.
- Is the winning criterion suitable for answer chaining?
- A leader board snippet would be nice, but I don't know how to modify the existing ones. If someone could provide such a snippet, I would be very grateful.
- Relevant tags?

Comment: I think decreasing the scores to `1` is more sensible, because otherwise I could write a submission using all (or even just one of) the zero-score characters a billion times (say, in a comment), keeping a "minimum" score, but then subsequent submissions would have completely absurd scores, and it'd be easy to outgolf later, leading to a boring answer chain.

Comment: You may want to correct "enter your code into the input field to calculate its score. Then add your code as a command-line argument,"

Comment: I think allowing all 256 bytes is a good idea because languages like Jelly, 05AB1E, etc. will more than likely use more than the printable ASCII chars.

Comment: "*While in principal Python 2.7.14 and Python 2.7.13 are different languages according to the site rules, I recommend to avoid using the fact that it is technically allowed as an excuse to post boring answers.*" Recommendations do not work, especially when they're as imprecise as this. (Are you "recommending" not treating Python 2 and Python 3 as separate languages? I have no idea). If you want to ban boring exploitation of the convention on different interpreters, ban it outright, but give a clear definition of how lines should be drawn.

Answer (score 6):

### 2 Spooky 4 Me

In terms of halloween, some things are just too spooky for me... Feel like we need some serious ***doots*** from skeletons to fuel our hallowed weens. So, in the spirit of that end, print the following, exactly as it is shown, if and only if the input ***does not equal "DOOT" (in all caps ONLY)***:

```
               _.---._
             .'       '.
             :)       (:
             \ (@) (@) /
              \   A   /
               )     (
               \"""""/
                '._.'
                 .=.
         .---._.-.=.-._.---.
        / ':-(_.-: :-._)-:' \
       / /' (__.-: :-.__) '\ \
      / /  (___.-' '-.___)  \ \
     / /   (___.-'^'-.___)   \ \
    / /    (___.-'='-.___)    \ \
   / /     (____.'='.____)     \ \
  / /       (___.'='.___)       \ \
 (_.:       '---'.=.'---'       :._)
 :||        __  _.=._  __        ||:
 :||       (  '.-.=.-.'  )       ||:
 :||       \    '.=.'    /       ||:
 :||        \    .=.    /        ||:
 :||       .-'.'-._.-'.'-.       ||:
.:::\      ( ,): O O :(, )      /:::.
|||| '     / /''--'--''\ \     ' ||||
''''      / /           \ \      ''''
         / /             \ \
        / /               \ \
       / /                 \ \
      / /                   \ \
     / /                     \ \
    /.'                       '.\
   (_)'                       '(_)
    \\.                       .//
     \\.                     .//
      \\.                   .//
       \\.                 .//
        \\.               .//
         \\.             .//
          \\.           .//
          ///)         (\\\
        ,///'           '\\\,
       ///'               '\\\
      ""'                   '""
```

---

However, if the input ***DOES equal "DOOT"***, in all caps only, print this instead:

```
               _.---._
             .'       '.
             :)       (:
             \ (@) (@) /
              \   A   /
               )     (
               \"""""/
                '._.'          ' ''''    _''|
                 .=.       @=====***===::_  |
         .---._.-.=.-._.---. (( \-@|_) )) `.|
        / ':-(_.-: :-._)-:' \ ]--------'"
       / /' (__.-: :-.__) '\ \   ||:
      / /  (___.-' '-.___)  \ \  ||:
     / /   (___.-'^'-.___)   \ \ ||:
    / /    (___.-'='-.___)    \ \||:
   / /     (____.'='.____)     \ ||:
  / /       (___.'='.___)       \||:
 (_.:       '---'.=.'---'       :._)
 :||        __  _.=._  __       
 :||       (  '.-.=.-.'  )      
 :||       \    '.=.'    /       
 :||        \    .=.    /      
 :||       .-'.'-._.-'.'-.       
.:::\      ( ,): O O :(, )   
|||| '     / /''--'--''\ \    
''''      / /           \ \
         / /             \ \
        / /               \ \
       / /                 \ \
      / /                   \ \
     / /                     \ \
    /.'                       '.\
   (_)'                       '(_)
    \\.                       .//
     \\.                     .//
      \\.                   .//
       \\.                 .//
        \\.               .//
         \\.             .//
          \\.           .//
          ///)         (\\\
        ,///'           '\\\,
       ///'               '\\\
      ""'                   '""
```

---

## Rules

- Trailing newlines and spaces are allowed.
- The design is horizontally symmetric, if you find inconsistencies let me know.

---

[Doot it up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypCfdrARoLQ), and enjoy!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[kolmogrov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogrov-complexity)

---

(Yes, I'm going to make it more official when posting on the actual SE)

Comment: What about this challenge ensures that the same old techniques won't be the best ones (i.e. that it adds value to the site)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor worse? Better? 10x worse? 10x better? I don't really know what makes the challenge unique beyond a formal proof that it is, but if the users enjoy it; why not allow it... current event challenges attract new users.

Answer (score 6):

## Check equation proofs in a ring

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [logic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

The recent [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf) to [prove that (-a)×(-a) = a×a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143822/a-%C3%97-a-a-%C3%97-a) attracted a number of faulty submissions, because there wasn't an easy way to verify the proofs. So, let's write some proof checkers.

#### Input

Your program should take a sequence of strings representing expressions in a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). *Valid expressions* consist of:

- Single-lowercase-letter variables (`a` to `z`)
- Two constants: the additive identity `0` and multiplicative identity `1`
- Compound expressions: `(X+Y)`, `(X*Y)` and `(-X)`, where `X` and `Y` stand for subexpressions. (The parentheses must always be present, and there must be no whitespace.)

#### Task

Your program should check whether:

- All strings except the first and last represent *valid* expressions.
- Each expression (after the first) can be obtained from the preceding expression, by substituting one of the [ring axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition) in the expression exactly once.

Output truthy if these conditions are met. Otherwise, output falsey.

You may assume that the first and last strings in the input are valid expressions. But your program must check the intermediate strings.

#### The ring axioms

For this challenge, use the following substitution rules (and do not use any others). Substitutions can go both left-to-right and right-to-left.

1. `(X+(Y+Z))` = `((X+Y)+Z)`
2. `(X+0)` = `X`
3. `(X+(-X))` = `0`
4. `(X+Y)` = `(Y+X)`
5. `(X*(Y*Z))` = `((X*Y)*Z)`
6. `(X*1)` = `X`
7. `(1*X)` = `X`
8. `(X*(Y+Z))` = `((X*Y)+(X*Z))`
9. `((X+Y)*Z)` = `((X*Z)+(Y*Z))`

### Scoring

Proof checkers are traditionally small, so that people can review them easily. Therefore, your program should be written in as few bytes as possible.

### Meta comments

Is the input format fair for most languages and approaches?

Usually, code-golf problems should not require input validation. However, I thought it would be appropriate behaviour for a proof checker. I think the current spec still accommodates regex-based solutions.

The format for the [original challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143822/a-%C3%97-a-a-%C3%97-a) also listed which axiom was used for each step. I could include this but I doubt that it improves the challenge much.

### Test cases

#### Valid proofs

```
(0+a)
(a+0)
a
```

```
(a*(-1))
((a*(-1))+0)
((a*(-1))+(a+(-a)))
(((a*(-1))+a)+(-a))
(((a*(-1))+(a*1))+(-a))
((a*((-1)+1))+(-a))
((a*(1+(-1)))+(-a))
((a*0)+(-a))
```

#### Invalid proofs

These proofs are missing intermediate steps.

```
(0+a)
a
```

```
(-0)
((-0)+0)
0
```

```
((a*0)+(-a))
(0+(-a))
```

This is simply untrue, so no proof should ever be accepted.

```
(a*b)
(b*a)
```

#### Invalid expressions

Your proof checker should reject if these appear partway through a proof.

```
a+b
```

```
(a+-b)
```

```
(a + b)
```

```
1+
```

```
42
```

Comment: You should include the ring axioms to make the post self-contained.

Answer (score 6):

## Chess ASCII Art, Knight

In honor of the world chess championship, in the shortest possible program, output the following ASCII art piece

```
      ,....,
   ,::::::<
  ,::/^\"``.
 ,::/, `   e`.
,::; |        '.
,::|  \___,-.  c)
;::|     \   '-'
;::|      \
;::|   _.=`\
`;:|.=` _.=`\
  '|_.=`   __\
   `\_..==`` /
    .'.___.-'.
   /          \
  ('--......--')
  /'--......--'\
   "--......--"
```

This is a **code-golf** challenge

Comment: You might want to make sure all the lines are aligned properly (they could be fine, since I'm on mobile and I know it can display differently, but it looks bent to me).

Comment: you're right, it was a little bent, I've reformatted it

Comment: Seems straightforward enough

Comment: lol, akin to image compression of pixel art in a very specific case :) I like the idea.

Comment: The very worst is approx 145 bytes + "verbatim output this". Be fun to see much better ones :)

Comment: Isn't the World Chess Championship already over? According to google it ended nov. 28th. ;) Did you forgot to post it?

Comment: Yeah, I made this post on November 23rd, cross-posting from sandbox eventually slipped my mind

Comment: @Thaufeki You could still post it, or are you going to wait a year? ;)

Comment: I would have to wait two, next one isn't until 2020! I'll post it now

Answer (score 6):

## Is this checkmate?

**Input**

A chess position in [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) format. You can assume the input is a valid chess position.

**Output**

Two distinct consistent outputs for checkmate or not.

**Examples**

[image]

```
8/8/8/8/8/5BKN/8/7k b - - 93 47
Mate
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

Comment: I suggest wording similar to “two distinct consistent outputs for checkmate or not”

Comment: @Quintec Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping it all self-contained and having a description for the FFN format, as well as a few more test cases

Comment: Is restricted to the FFN format a part of the challenge? Why not allow it in any reasonable format?

Comment: @Quintec why not just say truthy or falsey?

Comment: I suggest removing the restriction to FEN format, as it doesn't really add anything to the challenge, and specifying that the output be a truthy or falsey value as that is the usual spec for these types of challenges.

Answer (score 6):

### Lexicographically earliest valid UTF-8 byte sequence permutation

There are currently 1,114,112 possible Unicode characters (code points). Each character has a unique valid byte sequence in the UTF-8 encoding. Different characters have different length encodings:

- ASCII characters have a 1-byte encoding `00`-`7F`.
- The next 1920 characters have a 2-byte encoding `C2 80`-`DF BF`.
- The rest of the BMP has a 3-byte encoding `E0 A0 80`-`ED 9F BF` and `EE 80 80`-`EF BF BF`.
- The other planes have a 4-byte encoding `F0 90 80 80`-`F4 8F BF BF`.

It's possible for two strings (specific non-normalised sequences of Unicode code points) of Unicode to have byte sequences that are permutations of each other in a number of ways:

- One string could simply be a permutation of the other at the Unicode level, e.g. `ab` (`61 62`) and `ba` (`62 61`).
- UTF-8 continuation bytes could be switched between two characters, e.g. `¡â` (`C2 A1 C3 A2`) and `¢á` (`C2 A2 C3 A1`).
- UTF-8 continuation bytes could be switched within a character, e.g. `ᴵ` (`E1 B4 B5`) and `ᵴ` (`E1 B5 B4`).

For this challenge I would like you to write a program or function that finds the string whose UTF-8 byte sequence is lexicographically earliest of all such sequences that are permutations of the UTF-8 byte sequence of a given Unicode string.

For example, if your input is `ᵴ¢ába` (`E1 B5 B4 C2 A2 C3 A1 62 61`) your output would be `ab¡âᴵ` (`61 62 C2 A1 C3 A2 E1 B4 B5`).

Note however that some byte sequences are not valid UTF-8 (e.g. `E0 80 A0` which is an overlong encoding for a space) so you need to take care to avoid these.

It would be helpful if your "Try It Online" or similar link includes a footer that helps demonstrate the correctness of your output, where this is not obvious from the I/O format or code.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: For test cases, it will probably be a good idea to provide both strings and hex since I'd guess many languages will have to try both. Also this probably needs at least a link to an explanation of UTF8 continuation bytes.

Comment: "permutation of its canonical" should be "permutation of the input's canonical".

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman ... but I provided the hex? I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How about "I would like you to write a program or function that returns the Unicode string whose canonical UTF-8 byte sequence is the lexicographically earliest of all such sequences that are permutations of the canonical UTF-8 byte sequence of a given Unicode string"?

Comment: I meant in the example that you actually had, and presumably some number of test cases. I only mentioned it because I thought it was odd that you did it in the explanation but not the example.

Comment: @Neil Looks good. :)

Comment: I'm wary of the use of the word "*canonical*" in this question, because it raises issues in my mind about normalisation of Unicode strings. I think that the intended challenge is really about byte arrays with constraints on the most significant bits, and I think it would be better to make that explicit (and to make the constraints explicit).

Comment: @PeterTaylor There is that, but I wanted to exclude sequences such as `E0 80 A0`.

Comment: @Neil, I think there's a miscommunication here. I'm saying that instead of talking about Unicode strings the question should explicitly state the FSS-UTF constraints on byte sequences, and maybe rule out encoding UTF-16 surrogate codepoints and codepoints greater than 0x10FFFF.

Comment: @PeterTaylor OK but I really wanted this to be a string question rather than a byte sequence question...

Comment: The problem then is dealing with the lexicographically first rearrangement of `C3 A9` (é in normal form C) being `65 CC 81` (é in normal form D).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is that possible to do just by permuting the byte sequence?

Comment: No, and that's why I'm arguing that the question should be phrased in terms of byte sequences rather than strings.

Comment: There’s a mistake in the example: á is C3A1 and ¡ is C2A1. Good challenge. From the sound of it I/O will be flexible; this seems sensible since it keeps it open to more languages.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wanted it to be clear that these byte sequences must be a valid UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode string. I've tried rewriting the question a bit...

Comment: @NickKennedy Whoops, I got all of those wrong, I'd written `A0` instead of `A1` but also `A1` instead of `A2`. I think I've fixed it now...

Comment: "_Note however that some byte sequences are not valid UTF-8 (e.g. `E0 80 A0` which is an overlong encoding for a space) so you need to take care to avoid these._" Do we need to avoid all unprintables? EDIT: Nvm, I see we support the ranges you specified in the challenge description only?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, basically those are the valid byte sequences that will pass a conforming UTF-8 decoder.

Comment: Definitely improving. On a nitpick, most occurrences of *character* should really be *codepoint*. More problematically, my point about normalisation still stands. "***The** UTF-8 byte sequence of a given Unicode string*" (my emphasis) does not necessarily exist: there may be multiple UTF-8 byte sequences of a given Unicode string, which is a problem for test cases. E.g. `éo` in NFC would give `oé` but in NFD would give `eó`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added definitions of character and string. Many languages will tell you that `Å` and `Å` are different strings when using the default comparator, but e.g. JavaScript will compare them equal using `localeCompare`.

Answer (score 6):

[Compose Fill In The Blanks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188904/composing-fill-in-the-blanks)

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Ok I added some

Comment: Okay, I give /support (also, you may want to add disallowing standard loopholes and using any default io method to finish it up)

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Those are already standard I am not going to be making my post any more cluttered with stuff that adds nothing.

Answer (score 6):

## Move arrows along a contour

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188979/move-arrows-along-a-contour)

[ascii](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii) [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)

Comment: I've edited in a question since it needs 2D for clarity.

Comment: @Adám Only the arrows move. "+-|" always stay in place, or are "hidden" behind an arrow. So, you second example is correct (I deleted the first one)

Comment: Continuing @Adám's question: Are shapes always separated by at least one space, or can they be next to each other like `++++\n++++`, and we have to determine if it's a `++++\n++++` or `+--+\n+--+` based on the directions the arrows are facing? I.e. [is this a possible/valid input, and are those outputs correct?](https://pastebin.com/u2dUXFBt)

Comment: @GalenIvanov I didn't have anything but arrows move, and not it doesn't follow, because you couldn't tell what was behind the arrows, `-`s or `+`s which is what would make the two possible answers.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Example 2 has two adjacent shapes with no (vertical) spacing.

Comment: @Adám Ah, you're right. As for your question however, you'd still know `+<<+\n+>>+` is `+--+\n+--+` due to the directions of the arrows in combination with the rule "_when an arrow is on a corner, it keeps its current direction and changes it only after the turn is taken_". See the pastebin in my previous comment for some test cases where you do know it's `++++\n++++` instead, because of the arrow directions. `+^<+\n+>v+` will be two `++++\n++++` boxes, but `+<<+\n+>>+` will be one `+--+\n+--+` box.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good point, but OP actually never says that the input is an obtainable state, though it does make sense. I still have a feeling that there could be ambiguous cases.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The shapes will always be separated by at least one space, I'll add it to the description.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Probably better indeed to not have to deal with confusing ambiguous cases. In that case I would also have at least a newline separation, so test case 2 should be slightly modified. :)

Comment: @Adám Oh, I see - indeed I need to correct the second case to have a vertical space between the shapes.

Comment: Even single tracks can be incredibly difficult: `[" ++ ","++++","++^+"," ++ "]` only has one possible output: `[" ++ ","++++","+++>"," ++ "]`

Comment: @AdámYes, this is the only output. Do you think a condition that sharp turns are forbidden will help? (this means no two `+` can be adjacent)

Comment: @GalenIvanov Maybe that's indeed better to reduce confusion and make the challenge someone more manageable. Although you can still deduct the solution in Adam's comment above, having no spaces inside the space makes it rather difficult to parse correct. Always having at least one `|`/`-` between two `+` will always give the shapes always spaces, making it easier to parse individual shapes. In which case Adam's one would become `["  +-+  ","  | |  ","+-+ +-+","|     |","+-+ ^-+","  | |  ","  +-+  "]` -> `["  +-+  ","  | |  ","+-+ +-+","|     |","+-+ +>+","  | |  ","  +-+  "]`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, I added clarification.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Maybe also change the one Adam edited in, since it's still with `++` below one-another. :)

Comment: Is it also worth test cases for n greater than the length of one or more of the input contours, and n equal to an exact multiple of one or more of the input contours (in which case the output will be identical to the input)? I can't think of an approach which would work for the other test cases but would break for these, so this might not be necessary - mentioning just in case

Comment: @trichoplax Thank you for your feedback! I edited the order of directions. About the adjacent corners - I think they better never touch each other. I'll add test cases with only arrows/contour

Comment: You're welcome! Interesting challenge. Looking forward to seeing how people approach this

Answer (score 6):

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189240/repeated-factorials)

Comment: I found a lot of similar questions, but not quite the same. Would it be considered a duplicate?

Comment: we've had [double factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/double-factorial) closed before as a dupe of the vanilla factorial question

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! I found that post, but I thought the variable factorial range might make it considerably different from the original challenge.

Comment: Can we take input as two integers?

Comment: Can you give a definition for the multi-factorials above 2?

Comment: @Adám That makes the challenge somewhat easier, but I suppose it is fair. I added the other input option.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Yes! Totally skipped that part, oops. Is it clear enough like this?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Input numbers can be in any format, of course. I thought this was included in the default I/O rules, buy I will specify this in the challenge.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen In the input, at least one factorial sign is expected, i.e. a positive integer. I suppose the correct return value for a factorial number of zero would just be the base, but as the challenge is to calculate a factorial, this seems like an unreasonable restriction. The same goes for a factorial number *lager* than the base. If the factorial number is equal to the base, the base should be returned as per the generalized formula. I will add additional examples to clear this up. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The `range(start,stop,step)` function in Python 3 returns a generator with an initial value of `start` (or `0` if not specified) and a final value of `stop-1`. For example, the list representation of `range(1,4)` is `[1,2,3]`. If this list is sliced as `[1,2,3][::-1]`, the returned list is `[3,2,1]`, which can also be achieved with `range(3,0,-1)`. When the slicing operator is applied to the generator directly, a new generator is returned which generates the sliced list instead. Does that answer your question? Also, `range(420,0,-30)` would be a cleaner approach in this case.

Comment: @Jitse Ah ok, now it makes more sense. I indeed knew `range(1,4)` is `[1,2,3]`. And I also knew `[::-1]` reverses the order, since I see it used in answers every now and then. Seeing the `range(1,4)[::-1]` == `range(3,0,-1)` now I'm not sure why I didn't see it myself when I asked you the question. And yes, `range(value,0,-n)` would indeed be clearer than `range(1,value+1)[::-n]`. ;)

Comment: Seems good except maybe you should specify that \$n!^{(k)} = n\underbrace{!\ldots!}{k}\$  (n!^{(k)} = n\underbrace{!\ldots!}{k})

Answer (score 6):

## Cliquish Program

**Challenge:** Write a program that accepts a [character](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7764/31957) (or byte, see additional information) as input. Then:

1. If the character is contained within the source code, output a different character also in your source code.
2. If the character *is not* contained within the source code, output a different character also not in your source code.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program (in bytes) wins.

### Additional Information

- Your program must consist of at least 2 distinct characters.
- Your program must have at least 2 possible outputs.
- Your program does not have to be deterministic; it may output a character at random (with any distribution), so long as it conforms to the above criteria.
- Your program may optionally take a **byte** as input instead of characters. If you do, the code page the input is written in must contain at least each distinct byte in the source code, as well as at least two different bytes not in the source code.
- You may take input and give output in any reasonable way. For example, you may take input as a function parameter, a command-line argument, a line from STDIN, a triple-nested array containing a single character, etc. You could output via return value, STDOUT, exit code (if applicable), fax output, etc. The input and output formats must be consistent, however.
- Your output can only consist of the required character, optionally followed by one trailing newline. Prompt information (such as `ans =`) is exempt from this rule; such unpreventable output is acceptable.

Comment: Slightly more interesting than most generalised quines. Have you checked [tag:quine] for dupes?

Comment: @PeterTaylor [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89400/31957) [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104176/output-the-first-position-in-your-program-for-each-input-character) [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant). I couldn't find any exact dupes.

Comment: What if your program contains all but one possible character? What encoding are the characters in? UTF-8? latin-1? ASCII?

Comment: @Beefster Hopefully I've addressed your first question. As per your second, I believe we have a [standard consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7764/31957) on what a character is

Comment: By induction the program must have 4 possible outputs. Inside/outside of the source × two included in each (if choose one, output the other). Btw I don't understand the title

Answer (score 6):

## ASCII Maze Unrendering 3000

[maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191262/ascii-maze-rendering-3000)

Comment: Part of the wall for the current only test case seems a bit too narrow.

Comment: I think this could be considered a special case of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/print-ascii-voxels), with slight differences in the voxel style.

Comment: @flawr You're right. As written, this is a duplicate. Do you know if the reverse has been done, taking the 3d version and returning the original?

Comment: I don't think the reverse has been done, but I'm not sure this would make a good challenge. I'm still thinking about how one could make this. I mean the 2d version you propose would make it a bit simpler.

Comment: Yes. The full 3d version would almost certainly be impossible, because most voxels would be completely blocked. Here, every block is visible, and a human can figure out where the walls are, so a computer should be able to do it too.

Answer (score 6):

[Question link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193432/64722)

Comment: @Night2 Indeed, didn't notice that point, I fixed the samples in the rules to include AA-000-AA

Comment: Are the letters mandatory to be uppercased, or could we output in lowercase as well?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, letters are mandatory to be uppercase, also I feel like you ask that because of a builtin somewhere :P

Comment: Fine by me. I was mainly asking because it isn't a core-part of the challenge, and in some challenges lowercase/uppercase/mixed case is all allowed. But you're indeed right that lowercase would save a byte in my language of choice 05AB1E, where `A` is the lowercase alphabet builtin, and I'd need an additional `u` to uppercase it. ;p But since number plates are always uppercase, I can understand to keep the uppercase mandatory here as well. I had prepared a 24-byter, but will throw it away for now since I feel this can be done shorter.. Will try again later when it's posted to main. :)

Comment: Another question, or more recommendation: allowed both 0-based and 1-based indexing for answers. I see your test cases are 0-based, but some languages use 1-based indexing instead.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure, no problem with 1-based indexing, going to fix the rules to add that. As I've never used such languages, I often forget about them

Comment: I would say if the format irl has to be in uppercase then following that would be better. I've got myself an 85-byte JS answer that conforms to the irl format though.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto That's what I also advocate for, minus all the dumb real life rules that would just make it unfun to do. Anyway, going to post this

Answer (score 6):

## Almost Illegal Strings

[Posted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/214705/48931)

Comment: Does the challenge need to have the robber code output "Well done!"? What if they could just submit any code with the substring that runs?

Comment: @xnor That's fair enough - I just struggle to define 'program that runs'. Would you consider zero exit code and no stderr output reasonable? Or are there some languages that output to stderr even in a valid program?

Comment: I think this is too similar to the original "illegal strings" question which basically turned into a cops-and-robbers anyway

Comment: @Sisyphus I was thinking you could just copy whatever condition [Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/find-an-illegal-string) uses. But it doesn't seem to be that rigorous, saying "The compiler/interpreter/runtime must give an error when given any source code that contains your string as a substring." I think requiring no output to STDERR is probably fine. Maybe though some languages give warnings to STDERR that golfers typically ignore? Note that defaults allow programs that print then crash, so just requiring output doesn't preclude a fatal error after.

Comment: Rule suggestion: commenting out the almost illegal string is not allowed

Comment: I think it's too thorny to define what comments are in a way that works across languages. One objective way to handle it would be to let cops specify a set of characters that are not in their code, where they might include their language's comment character(s) or quote literals.

Comment: @xnor Ok, I've rewritten the challenge to just require that the program does not error, and feel the rules are fairly straightforward and watertight.

Comment: @Beefster I considered this, and something like xnor's suggestion of banning characters. However, I think it ruins the purity of the challenge a bit, and for most languages it's very easy to avoid being in a comment (newline + end of comment block will do it). There are some languages which have 'inescapable comments', such as raw strings with specific delimiters, or something like Perl's `__END__`, but they're sacrifices I'm willing to make.

Comment: The problem with not banning comments (or including things within strings, for that matter) is that it's quite easy to cop out and write a hello world with the almost illegal string appended in a comment. That takes out all the challenge. xnor's suggestion solves that mostly, but that does end up limiting cops a little bit to make the robbers' job an actual challenge.

Comment: @Beefster Apologies, I have not been clear about my reasoning. My logic is that for the vast majority of languages, a cop can 'comment proof' their string trivially by adding a newline (to escape a single line comment) and an end of comment block (to end a multiline comment). For example, the string `\nx"""x'''` (with a literial newline) escapes all Python comments. You can do this in most languages - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Beefster It looks like you were right - it is too hard without allowing Cops to ban characters. I'd like to apologise for not taking your feedback more seriously while the question was in the sandbox.

Answer (score 6):

## [Speed of Lobsters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217690/speed-of-lobsters)

Answer (score 6):

## [Print random integers until 0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218138/print-random-integers-until-0)

Comment: Presumably, if the first number is zero, we just output zero and exit?

Comment: "integers may be separated by any non-digit, non-empty separator" can we output in zero-padded form (`00 01 .. 98 99`) so that a separator isn't necessary? What about codepoints/byte values (`NULL` - `c`)? Can it be a list-like object rather than a separated string? I think this would be better with more [tag:sequence]-like IO rules

Comment: @pxeger Yes, if the first number is zero, you just output zero and exit. I don't think the standard is to output with zero-padding, so I'll say no on that. Byte values and list objects are both standard forms of outputting a bunch of numbers, so of course, those are allowed

Comment: Also, I assume it is not necessary that the program follows the indicated procedure (which would be unobservable anyway), as long as the output has the same statistical properties. So if a different procedure is used, perhaps the answer writer should justify it. (For example: generate a number K geometrically distributed with parameter 1/99, then output K nonzero numbers, then output a 0)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, I'm pretty sure that "you don't have to follow the letter of the challenge so long as the behaviour is the same" is a standard rule, but in case not, I've edited in a sentence along with your example

Comment: I didn't fully define my example, sorry. You may want to change it to "then output K independent numbers with a uniform distribution on the set {1, 2, ..., 99}". That corresponds to the procedure you specify with a uniform distribution on {0, 1, ..., 99}.

Comment: @cairdCoinheringaahing are built-in functions for generating pseudo-random numbers forbidden? If not, is the challenge a very trivial one or am I missing something?

Comment: @Davide Trivial challenges are not necessarily bad, since it encourages participation in relatively hard-to-use or minimal esolangs. And I think this one is actually good because I smell many unexpected approaches to golf the problem. (Also, banning built-ins are considered bad.)

Comment: @Bubbler thank you so much for this train of information

Comment: @Davide Nope, all builtins are allowed. As Bubbler said, trivial challenges are only really bad if there’s no room for interesting solutions, which I don’t think is the case here

Answer (score 6):

## [Remove Nth occurrences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219631/remove-nth-occurrences)

Comment: There is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204772/look-for-n-plicates) but it got closed, Everything is clear, but can you replace, "the n" with "the integer n" in the last point of your assumptions list. For some reason that made me read the sentence multiple times.

Comment: Is there a reason for limiting the array values to 1-9?

Comment: @pxeger [Because the values don't matter](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/66833), so there's no reason to complicate it more. Plus, it can allow for some interesting string based approaches by taking \$A\$ as a single string

Comment: @pxeger It certainly helps that 0 cannot be part of the array, because then I can use it to erase values in APL. I'm sure other languages can take advantage of that too

Answer (score 6):

## To raise \$ e \$ to the power of a matrix [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230784)

---

### Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: why not require exact calculation, it makes for a harder challenge but a more interesting one

Comment: @rak1507 it's irrational so an exact value can't be calculated

Comment: looked like there were methods on wikipedia but I could be wrong

Comment: Note that the exponential of a 9x9 matrix of 100's exceeds what floats can represent. You might want to lower the 100 bound or make allowances for that.

Comment: I think the precision convergence rule is too restrictive and too tied to that specific power series method, and some loose accuracy bound would allow more varied methods. For instance, one can approximate \$e^M \approx (I+M/n)^n\$ for large \$n\$.

Comment: @xnor I didn't read much into the matrix exponential (because I couldn't find the article on Wikipedia and was too busy watching the rest of the 3b1b video :P), so I hadn't not really realised there were other ways to compute it. What would you recommend? I still like the idea of requiring it to be observed to converge within floating point limits, because it adds an extra layer of challenge rather than just "repeat this step 100 times", but maybe that just isn't practical

Comment: I think convergence within floating point limits would unfortunately be hard and finicky here because of the nature of exponentials. The same way that \$e^{100}\$ and \$e^{100.001}\$ differ a lot, small errors in the computation can accumulate into huge ones. Also, the values in the output might be extremely small and become represented as zero. I'd have to think more about bounds, but maybe something like every entry within either 1% or 1e-4 of the true one should work.

Comment: My solution to floating-point errors is "the result should be within [insert error bound here] relative error **for the given test cases**". (The bolded part is VERY important. FP computation methods often have errors dependent on the magnitude of the input, so it is very hard to judge if an implementation is valid, even if the possible input range is specified. Explicitly giving the test cases makes it much easier to test submissions. Also, you need to craft the test cases carefully so that you don't accidentally ban a valid method or allow invalid methods.)

Answer (score 6):

## Non-quining infinite printer

*Seems like the title could be better but I'm not sure what to do instead*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

I have heard that a monkey typing random keys on a typewriter, given infinite time, will eventually type out the entire works of Shakespeare, and in fact type out every possible string of characters of any length. This sounds to me like the basis for a profitable business venture in publishing. Unfortunately, however, as a result of previous failed business ventures, I am legally barred from possessing either monkeys or typewriters, so I'll instead need a program. I want this program to provably generate every possible string of characters, assuming infinite time and memory. Repetition is fine, as is overlap, as long as every possible string appears somewhere in the output. There's a catch, though. I imagine once my business gets off the ground and people realize the potential profits, they might want to get their hands on my program. The trouble is that since I'm outputting every possible string of text, in theory I'll eventually end up outputting the program itself, leaving it open to be stolen. To prevent this, I want the program never to output its own source code. It should still output every other possible string, just not itself (or, obviously, any strings which it is a substring of). Because my funds are currently very tight, I can't afford to pay for more bytes than are necessary, so I'm seeking the shortest possible program that does the job (This is a `code-golf` challenge, shortest answer in bytes wins). *Is it communicated well enough what this challenge is asking for? Should I add a TL;DR and/or a more technical explanation of what's being looked for?*

Additional notes:

- I've had enough run-ins with the law in previous ventures, I'd like this one to go smoothly. So no abusing [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) in the program, please.
- Given that this program is my financial plan for the next infinity years, I'd like some reassurance that it actually does what it's supposed to. Please provide at least a brief explanation of why your code works, since it can't exactly be tested.
- Any character encoding is fine, please specify though. The exception is that your source code must be printable in the encoding you use. *Is this a reasonable way to handle this that is fair to all languages?*
- No reading your own source, because that makes quine-related holes uncool, and uncoolness does not fit with my businesses' brand persona.

Comment: How are the strings in the output separated? Some previous challenges about "print all possible strings" were closed as unclear because of this.

Comment: @Bubbler The strings don't have to be separated. What I mean is that every string should be a substring of the "main" output if that makes sense. Put another way, running a regex match on the output for any string of characters (other than the source) should return at least one result. Would adding something to that effect clear up that confusion?

Comment: *It should still output every other possible string, just not itself (or, obviously, any strings which it is a substring of)* Okay, the task makes sense now. I think you'll need to add that information somewhere before the sentence I quoted. Now I wonder if the task is actually possible...

Comment: @Bubbler Sure, it's possible. One approach is to store the program's source in a string, and then run some sort of code that generates every possible string, checking after each generation whether the generated string contains the source string, and only printing if it doesn't. There might be some trouble in making sure the source isn't present in a combination of two consecutively generated strings (i.e. if the source code is `AB`, then outputting `XA` and `BX` consecutively is an issue), but a simple solution to that is to insert a character not present in the source between each pair.

Comment: Here's an implementation in Python https://tio.run/##nZFBb4JAEIXv8yumJ3erNVLDpQm99C94Kx4IjoVEd8mwpDRNfzvdRSxiQYhHZt97M7wv@zKJVuuqSo@ZZoNMACUGOPv7DlWo3OT7gX9CleuCY3rTO7KjcrnXfIyMKKVTfZAijozmDZXGPr@vtm78maQHwg0X9BIqxI7KSnAeoOcebBZmOsdUIUc2TBxIiY5ayjoBMd1fxVjfFl/x2fexkTQyFxgE@D8Kn9C7kF7ddboeH7HnCJyjJ1snHXIaDjpdFuDqpsJFtkXowu3PDQt57iVOInbFdJzNViu3zjhh4VS1xf640g7eMqeI40S02BZWfq4x41QZ4fzOvfblgtQuqBfLGQyhhp6mAC4owwBkmMgYRhHDZMJwL2Do8IUxvDCJLnTgwi220IMWJpCFMbBV9Qs

Comment: @jeje An easily thought solution is just use an unused char as split, but that likely be longer

Comment: What do mean by "all possible strings"? Is this restricted to all strings consisting of printable ASCII? The entire Unicode table?

Answer (score 6):

## [Who Is Kevin Bacon?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240705)

Comment: > I'm worried it will just be "string a load of combinatorial builtins together" and brute-force it That's a solution to pretty much anything

Comment: it looks interesting enough, I can't find anything similar with searches like "Erdos number" and such. It will inevitably get a trivial golflang answer, especially with felxible input methods. To control quality, maybe adding a [tag:restricted-time] would help.

Answer (score 6):

## [Sort every dimension](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241650/sort-every-dimension)

Answer (score 6):

## [Output a random unary string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243525/output-a-random-unary-string)

Comment: Would printing an infinite stream of separators or `x`s be valid? It's an infinitesimally small chance that just, e.g., one `x` is ever printed for the rest of time, but does that count (I'd be inclined to say no)?

Comment: i have no idea what this challenge is about but +1

Comment: Since most languages random number generator (RNG) only have finite state, The program won't output infinity number of different outputs. You may argue that we may consider (assume) RNG have infinity digits (precision). But then, someone would argue that `repeat("x", floor(1/random_between_0_and_1()))` is a valid submission as we can consider the output of `random_between_0_and_1` have infinity precision. It is not very clear which is valid and which is not to me.

Comment: Looks like "the RNG in use has perfect random distribution" is a necessary assumption, but allowing the return value of RNG to be of infinite precision sounds a bit weird, as tsh pointed out. You may want to clarify these points in the challenge rules. (I'm not entirely against it though; in some langs the only source of randomness is a random real number in `[0,1)`, which makes some compromises like "you can only use RNGs that return a finite number of integers" unsuitable)

Comment: @tsh @Bubbler Do you think the rule I just added is adequate? (I think tsh's suggested `repeat("x", floor(1/random_between_0_and_1()))` should be considered valid as long as it never causes a division by zero.)

Comment: @pxeger I cannot understand how `random_between_0_and_1` output a "infinite precision" number in finite time (so program will halt with with probability 1). But regardless this, the rule seems clear to me.

Comment: @tsh Well obviously nothing can output an infinite precision number of any kind, but I'm allowing it as an assumption because I think it should be considered a valid possible solution.

Comment: Does "Every possible length of `x`s" includes 0 (empty output)?

Comment: @tsh "You may choose whether to include the empty string as a possible output"

Answer (score 6):

[Building spikes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/building-spikes)

Comment: Interesting idea. I think the challenge could be interesting if solutions were required to take in a size and output a spiked building of that size.

Comment: @ophact is it better now?

Comment: Why input 7 is one line taller than input 2?

Comment: @tsh its same height

Answer (score 6):

## [Sort numbers in a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244101/sort-numbers-in-a-ragged-list/)

Comment: Can the output be flattened?

Comment: @BgilMidol No, that defeats the point of it.

Comment: I think to avoid ambiguity it should be said something like "The shape of the output must be the same as the shape of the input".  The spec is currently pretty sparse, relying mostly on an example.

Answer (score 6):

## King of the Holster (EXITING SANDBOX TOMORRROW)

I realized there hadn't been a King of the Hill in forever, so I wanted to create one.

### Before the Game

You will be given 10 points to distribute between HP, Dexterity, Armor, and Speed. You may distribute up to 10 points between these categories (integer amounts only). You do not have to put a point in each category.

- Your HP will equal 10 plus the number of points you put in HP.
- Your Dexterity (chance of dodging a hit) is equal to 0.04 times the number of points you put in Dexterity. For example, if you put 8 points in Dex, you would have a .32 chance of dodging a hit.
- Your Armor (chance of taking 1 less damage from a hit) is equal to .1 times the number of points you put into Armor.
- Your Speed is simply equal to the number of points you put in Speed.
- You always start with 2 ammo.

### Gameplay

Agents will be ordered based on their speed, with ties being broken at random before the game begins. On their turn, each agent will be given their HP, all of their stats (max HP, Dexterity, Armor, and Speed), how much ammo they have, who they attacked most recently, and who attacked them most recently.

On each agent's turn, there are three possible moves:

- Heal: If not at maximum HP, gain 1 HP.
- Reload: Gain 2 ammo.
- Shoot: Choose another agent. They get a random real from 0 to 1. If that number is less than their dexterity, they dodge and take 0 damage. Otherwise, they take a random integer amount of damage from 1 to 4, then they generate another random real from 0 to 1. If that number is less than their armor, they take 1 less damage.

TLDR: Shooting does 0 damage if they dodge, 0 to 3 if they get armor but no dodge, 1 to 4 if none.

Once an agent's HP is less than 0, it is out and can no longer take actions. Last agent surviving wins the round.

### Scoring

Each round, if there were X agents, your agent receives X points for each agent below it. Therefore, in a 10 player game, the top agent would get 9 points, the second would get 8, and so on. I can currently run 5000 3-player modes in 10 or so seconds (probably much faster if I removed some of the printing for debugging), so as long as nobody's agent takes too long to run, I should be able to run thousands of score tests.

### I/O

Currently, submissions will create a class which extends PlayerClass. It will create a new class constructor that takes no inputs, which will call `super()` with the points it wants in each category. Additionally, you will redefine the makeMove function, which takes no inputs and calls `move()` with whatever arguments are required.

### Rules

Submissions in Java only. As long as the submission is simple enough, I might be able to translate from pseudocode/some other language to Java though.

No calling any methods of other entities using shenanigans. The biggest problem here is `takeDamage()`, which has to be public so it can be called when someone is shot. Other than that, there shouldn't be any public functions other than turn-order functions, which are probably fine to access.

No redefining any functions/variables of PlayerClass besides `makeMove()`.

The subclass constructor must be of the form `super(x,y,z,a);` and cannot overwrite the requirements in the PlayerClass constructor.

You may define other methods within your class IF they are only called as part of generating your stats or deciding who to shoot and they follow the rules outlined above.

Don't make your code take forever. This KOTH is pretty lightweight, so there shouldn't be a need for complex algorithms.

---

The controller and four basic test agents can be found here:
https://github.com/romanpwolfram/GunfightKoTH/tree/main

Challenge name by tjjfvi.

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Java right now, but it's simple enough that I can probably convert it to another language with a bit of work.

Comment: How much damage does getting shot do?

Comment: Random from 1 to 4, but random from 0 to 3 if they "win" their armor roll.

Comment: > I realized there hadn't been a King of the Hill in forever

*[sad noises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242969/king-of-the-ziggurat)*

Comment: That one looked like a good KoTH, and I have no idea why it failed. Reasonably complex strategy, but easy enough to code.

Comment: Watch out, a player can just do `ammo = 10000` and get away with it. Might want to make em private and instead put getters.

Comment: Ok. I think I can change all of them since all the info you need should come from getInfo and getAlivenemies

Answer (score 6):

## [Convert Alpha-3 to Alpha-2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246777/107262)

Comment: If that link goes down, or if the list changes for any reason (such as by adding a new country), it would invalidate existing answers.  The usual way around this is to declare one unchanging list of every country/territory code that needs to be handled, even if the external resource changes.  Since the full list looks too large to comfortably fit in a post, you could copy the list into a Pastebin or something.

Comment: Yep! I was planning on posting one to my website later today!

Comment: @Nitrodon done!

Answer (score 6):

## [Shortest restricted superstring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246909)

Comment: *please* don't enforce answers having to handle the empty set as either input but especially the first. It's just an annoying edge case.

Answer (score 6):

## ITEXTIN - Is This an EXTended Initialism?

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) Please write a program or function that, when given a list of words and proposed extended initialism, outputs whether it is valid.

Rules:

- The list will contain at least two words.
- The extended initialism will contain at least three letters.
- Each word in the phrase contributes a prefix to the extended initialism.
- This prefix must not be the whole word.
- In the case of the first and last words, the prefix must not be empty.
- The extended initialism is the concatenation of these prefixes.
- Inputs are alphabetic only, your choice of upper or lower case.
- Separators, if you want them, are any symbol or white space.

Examples (truthy):

```
laser=light amplification by the stimulated emission of radiation
radar=radio detection and ranging
```

Examples (falsy):

```
labyser=light amplification by the stimulated emission of radiation
radar=light amplification by the stimulated emission of radiation
dear=radio detection and ranging
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: How should a function determine whether to exclude words such as `by`, `the`, `of` or `and`?

Comment: @jezza_99 By looking at which letters it needs.

Comment: Surely then `labtseor` is correct, not `laser`, by "Each word in the phrase contributes a prefix to the extended initialism."

Comment: @jezza_99 Empty prefixes are allowed except for the first and last words.

Comment: Can we assume the input initialism is always at least 2 characters long? If not, can we at least assume it's non-empty?

Comment: @pxeger Hmm, 2 characters is still a bit of an edge case, since it can only ever be the first character of the first and last words... maybe I should make it at least 3? What do you think?

Comment: @Neil I don't exactly see anything wrong with just `>=2`, but to completely minimise any problem you could go with `>=3` to be safe.

Comment: @pxeger How about the list of words? I've gone with `>=2` there for now.

Answer (score 6):

## Scribble Pad for Nerds.

## [Posted Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248244/scribble-pad-for-nerds)

Comment: I suggest allowing a matrix of characters as output too ([relevant meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14531/55372)). Maybe even allow a boolean matrix as output?

Comment: @pajonk Ah yeah, thanks!

Comment: Maybe Give Examples for intersecting lines or diagonal lines?

Comment: @Nobody finished!

Comment: The `[6, 4, 2]` example is unclear. If each movement draws 2 `#`s, why are there 7 total `#`s? I'm guessing that the board begins with 1 `#` already drawn, and instructions start from there, but this isn't made clear. In fact, if so, the image for the `[6, 4, 2]` explanation is wrong, as it says "start at the `X`", when the `X` is one space too far to the right. Also, I believe you have left and right mixed up with `2` and `6` in the explanation?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing oh frick yeah, I'm gonna fix it later, thanks

Answer (score 6):

## [Count alternating permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248143)

Answer (score 6):

## [Create Bernard from Desmos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248820/create-bernard-from-desmos)

Comment: Might want to include [this animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xcit0jxp3b) for understanding the algorithm as listed. However, that algorithm is a bit complicated because it describes the reason for the pattern forming; you could keep it at the end, but I'd suggest describing the result matrix in terms of rectangles: Quadrants 3 and 4 are filled with 1s, as well as quadrant 1.1 and 1.2, then recurse on quadrant 1.4. (where quadrant a.b is the `b`th quadrant of the `a`th quadrant, and quadrants are numbered counter-clockwise starting from 1=top right quadrant)

Comment: Please take a screenshot of bernard in case this specific manifestation of the bug is fixed or changed, for posterity

Comment: @thejonymyster OK will do

Answer (score 6):

## [Enumerate the Microwave Timer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249143/doing-a-little-trolling-with-the-microwave-timer)

Comment: Now I wanna try this on my microwave :P

Comment: Can the output times be `[second, minute]`?

Comment: @steffan that's covered under the reasonable format rule

Answer (score 6):

## [Extract the word containing this index](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249129)

Comment: can we take input as list of words?

Comment: @Steffan I didn't want to allow that, because it means there are indices that fall on the boundaries of words with no corresponding value, which I think would unnecessarily complicate the rules and confuse the challenge for little benefit. If you can make a good case for why it should be allowed, I'm all ears.

Comment: This is a delightful problem. It seems like it should be trivial, but it's not exactly. And I can think of multiple ways to do it that are competitive with each other in my chosen language.

Comment: @chunes Thank you! My favourite challenges are exactly those like this one: despicably simple, with numerous possible approaches. I find the best source of inspiration for these is problems I encounter in real-world programming.

Answer (score 6):

## [Live a longer life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251510/66833)

Comment: Winning criterion?

Comment: Here are two of my suggestions in chat as a reminder: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61851078#61851078) [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61857652#61857652)

Comment: Both \$n=1\$ and \$n=2\$ have better options: `[[1]]` and `[[1,1],[1,0]]` (or `o!` and `2o$o!` respectively in RLE format). Both take one generation (instead of zero) to reach a fixed board.

Comment: If you intend to post both n=1 and 2 yourself, specifically picking p1=0 (empty board) and p2=1 (e.g. a triangle by alephalpha) would be more consistent with the rules.

Answer (score 6):

## Introduction

Raku's [sequence operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_...) is very flexible.  It does a lot of different things, but for the purposes of this challenge, we'll focus on two particular features:

- Given two integers, it counts up or down as appropriate.  `1 ... 5` => `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`; `9 ... 5` => `(9, 8, 7, 6, 5)`.
- It can occur multiple times in the same expression, and will count up or down from one argument to the next.  `4 ... 6 ... 3 ... 1 ... 2` => `(4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2)`.

## Challenge

Write a function that accepts a list of integers (or a number of integer parameters) and returns a list of the integers that would be produced by inserting Raku's sequence operator between the input integers.  That is, between each adjacent pair of input numbers `a` and `b`, insert an ascending sequence of integers from `a + 1` to `b - 1` if `a < b`, and a descending sequence of integers from `a - 1` to `b + 1` if `a > b`.  But also:

- If `| a - b | == 1`, insert nothing between them.
- If `a == b`, include just one copy of `a` in the output list.

Lowest byte count wins.  Raku answers which employ the sequence operator are disallowed.

## Test Cases

```
1, 5 -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
20, 17 -> (20, 19, 18, 17)
1, 3, 1 -> (1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5 -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
5, 4, 6, 3, 7 -> (5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
100, 100, 100, 100 -> (100)
```

Comment: @thejonymyster To me it doesn't look like substantially more background info than many other challenges provide.  But perhaps I can pare it down to a few sentences rather than a bulleted list.

Comment: Consider adding something about permitted IO e.g that default [I/O Rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) while standard loopholes are forbidden and a winning criterion e.g. this is `code-golf`, the shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 6):

## Fractional Unicode Bars

Your program should take as input a number `n` and output a bar composed of `n // 8` ▉ characters (U+2588), as well as a final character which should be one of ▊ ▋ ▌ ▍ ▎▏(U+2589 to U+258F) representing `n % 8`. If `n % 8` is 0, your program should not output any additional characters. This is difficult to explain well in text, so here are some examples:

```
Input: 8
Output: ▉
Input: 32
Output: ▉▉▉▉
Input: 33
Output: ▉▉▉▉▏
Input: 35
Output: ▉▉▉▉▍
Input: 246
Output: ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▊
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Answer (score 6):

### Output the ground-state configutation of an element [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Task: Given the atomic number as input, output the ground-state electron configuration.

### Background info

In each orientation per orbital, there can be at most 2 electrons. Specifically:

- The `s` orbital has 1 orientation, so it can be filled with a maximum of 2 electrons.
- The `p` orbital has 3 orientations, so it can be filled with a maximum of 6 electrons.
- The `d` orbital has 5 orientations, so it can be filled with a maximum of 10 electrons.
- The `f` orbital has 7 orientations, so it can be filled with a maximum of 14 electrons.

et cetera.

The orbitals per orbit level are listed like so:

```
1s
2s 2p
3s 3p 3d
4s 4p 4d 4f
5s 5p 5d 5f ...
```

Based on the Aufbau priciple, we order the orbitals diagonally, so the energy order of these orbitals is like this:

```
1s < 2s < 2p < 3s < 3p < 4s < 3d < 4p < 5s < 4d < 5p < ...
```

The orbitals with higher energy levels are only filled up if all of the lower energy level orbitals are completely filled. Taking Na (atomic number 11) as an example:

```
1s^2, 2s^2, 2p^6, 3s^1
```

(`2p^6` means there are 6 electrons in the `2p` orbital, and so on.)

Finally, we put that in order and output the electrons at the specfied level:

```
1: 1s^2
2: 2s^2 2p^6
3: 3s^1
```

So `2, 8, 1` is our output.

### Testcases

```
1 -> [1]
3 -> [2, 1]
9 -> [2, 7]
10 -> [2, 8]
13 -> [2, 8, 3]
21 -> [2, 8, 9, 2]
28 -> [2, 8, 16, 2]
29 -> [2, 8, 18, 1]
34 -> [2, 8, 18, 6]
41 -> [2, 8, 18, 12, 1]
48 -> [2, 8, 18, 18, 2]
115 -> [2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 5]
```

Comment: I assume the task is: Given the atomic number as input, output the ground-state electron configuration. Is this right? If so, please clarify in the post.

Comment: @Jacob Yes. I'll add that in the post.

Comment: You might want to add the test case `46 -> [2, 8, 18, 16, 2]` to make clear that we are not considering the _actual_ electron configurations. (Palladium's actual config is `[2, 8, 18, 18]`.)

Answer (score 6):

## Display integer in balanced base-ϕ

### Objective

Given a **positive** integer, display it in balanced base-ϕ numeral. ϕ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

### Balanced base-ϕ

Unlike [the usual base-ϕ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base) that uses 0 and 1 as digits, *balanced* base-ϕ uses 1 and -1 as digits. Still, every integer can be represented by a terminating expansion.

-1 is written `T` as a shorthand.

To ensure uniqueness of the representation, there are some restrictions:

- `1TT` cannot appear anywhere (while the radix point is ignored). To get rid of it, it can be replaced by `T11`.
- The least significant digit must be `1`.

Even with these restrictions, there still is an integer whose representation isn't unique, namely 2. For the purpose of this challenge, you can output either `1T1` or `1.11`.

### Examples

```
Decimal, Balanced base-ϕ
1, 1
2, 1T1 or 1.11
3, 1T1.11
4, 11.1111
5, 111.T1
6, 111.1T1111
7, 11T1.1T1111
8, 1T111.T111
9, 111T.111111
10, 1111.1T1T1111
11, 1111.111111
12, 1T11T1.111111
13, 1T111T.111T1111
14, 1T1111.T11111
15, 1T1111.111T1111
16, 11111.T1T1
17, 11T1T1.111T1111
18, 11T11T.11T111
19, 1T11.11T111
20, 11T111.11T111
```

## Meta Question

How can I prove that balanced base-ϕ covers all integers? Are there any other integers whose representation isn't unique?

Comment: To prove this covers all numbers you can probably use the fact that every integer has a representation as a sum of distinct Lucas numbers, and the formula \$L_n = \phi^n + (-\phi)^{-n}\$.

Comment: Funny! I just added base conversion to my language and thought: Why restrict it to integer bases? Now I come back and see this challenge! I found a challenge about [base conversion with float numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139397/real-base-conversion?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C22.0197), but none with float base so far (or did I miss it?). Should this maybe be first before getting more complicated with balanced base?

Answer (score 6):

## [Find the largest sum such that no two elements are touching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265382/find-the-largest-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-touching)

Comment: I’d replace the for some k in N MathJax bit with “for some positive integer k”. Personally I don’t think the polynomial time constraint really makes this any more interesting, but it’s your challenge.

Comment: @noodleman Polynomial time prevents solutions that check all subsets

Comment: Actually, your examples contain zero, which is no *positive integer*. You probably mean *non-negative integers*?

Comment: @Philippos I fixed the example

Answer (score 6):

## [Print the answer before a given answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265561/print-the-answer-before-a-given-answer)

Comment: I think you should add [tag:quine], because you need to output your own source code (although only given a certain input)

Comment: Currently it might make sense for answers to encode the data they are printing somehow (maybe even in a highly language-specific way), so following answers will either have to write their own encoder or duplicate all earlier programs. Is this something you want?

Comment: To clarify my comment: the usual solution would be something like `A = 'somecode'; B = 'print({A})'; C = 'print({B})'; ...; Q = quine; arr = [A, B, C, ..., Q]; print(arr[arr.index(input()) - 1 % N])`, but if `C`, for example, has a very weird encoding of `B`'s code, then you couldn't reuse `B`'s code you already produced, and will have to either to write a long encoding code or copy the encoded `B`, and I'm not sure if this is something you want or not

Comment: How would this work with languages that use different character encodings, should the program output the same (Unicode) characters or the same sequence of bytes.

Comment: You should add the first answer as the cat program, so nobody else can do it.

Comment: @bsoelch That's a good question, I think I'll go with bytes. Since some languages can't do byte I/O directly, they could always just use Unicode chars 0-255 and pretend they're bytes.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Good point, maybe I will. If one got submitted that was either empty or overly complex, it could break the challenge quite a bit

Comment: why are negative score answers invalid? is this [tag:code-shuffleboard] :P? my reading is that your score is the percent increase between previous answer and your own... if your code is shorter than previous, that would be a negative percent... whats the big idea :-)

Comment: @thejonymyster If you're score's a negative percent change, that's still valid and treated the same. Didn't think of that case tho, I assume it probably won't happen

Comment: asking because your draft currently explicitly says "Answers with a negative score are invalid", so im not sure what you were trying to get at there, and then there's a clause about how invalid answers can be ignored... seeing as theres no other score modifiers, i have no idea what you intended there. :o might wanna read the whole thing over one more time

Comment: @thejonymyster Ohhh I meant negative score as in votes. So if someone does something annoying, you can downvote their answer enough to invalidate it

Comment: Ahhh lmao ok that also explains why you referenced "score" before giving the "scoring" rule. your edit clears it up. good mechanic btw

Comment: If negative-voting answers are invalid, I could just downvote a new answer to allow me to take it’s place. This doesn’t seem fair. I suggest doing something like -3 or lower to be invalid.

Comment: Also, am I allowed to use `open(__file__).read()` to get the source code?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer No, I'll clarify no reading source code or external resources is allowed

Answer (score 6):

### Minimum Escaping [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

Your task is to write 2 functions/programs. They may share code.

The first function must, given a string and a character, output a new string that does not contain that character.

The second function must, given the string from the previous function and the excluded character, reconstruct the original string.

All input strings will be ASCII printable, all output strings must be ASCII printable. You may choose to include or exclude whitespace.

#### Examples

One could try to use replace the character with an escape sequence. For example `\#bcda` with excluded character becomes `\\#bcd\#` then you'd know to replace `\#` with whatever character is excluded. However, the excluded character might itself be `#`  or `\` so if one uses this method they'd need to be able to dynamically switch to a different escape sequence in that case.

There is no length limit for the censored string so you could try to encode the entire string in unary, but be careful that the unary char you choose may not be the excluded char.

This is code golf, shortest answer in each language wins. Brownie points for interesting solutions even if they are not the shortest though.

Answer (score 5):

#### Table parser, code golf

Input

```
|===========|=============|==============|
|Left align |  Right align| Center align |
|===========|=============|==============|
|This       |         This|     This     |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|                column                  |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|will       |                            |
|-----------|          will be           |
|be         |                            |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|left       |        right|    center    |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|aligned    |      aligned|   aligned    |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|and can be |    vertical-|              |
|multilined | align middle|  as default but a bit long line |
|with <br>  |             |              |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
```

Output should be valid HTML. And I am thinking of following requirement specs.

- alignments (left, right, middle)
- border thickness (normal -, |, bold, =,||)
- with table headers or without
- rowspans, colspans
- multiline & vertical-align is always middle

What do you think?

Comment: I guess figuring out cells and row/colspans is enough work, so handling bold and italic could be omitted, maybe.

Comment: Also, should this be a code golf or a challenge?

Comment: code-golf @joey. and I am gonna leave bold and italic out. I was not sure it was hard enough :D

Comment: Can cells contain more than a line of text? I.e. do long contents wrap or do they extend the cell?

Comment: @Joey, yeah, a bit more complicated now, multiline involve vertical-align, so I set that as middle as default, what do you think?

Comment: Yikes :D. Well, I was just pondering a few ways of figuring out the layout and determining rowspans would be much easier if all rows are the same height ;). Should be ok, but bear in mind that it makes judging correct vertical align difficult. Given the current last row the valigns could be either one of `mmm`, `ttm`, `tmm`, `btm`, `bmm`. No show-stopper but something to keep in mind for test cases and scripts.

Comment: @Joey, yeah, to judge top, middle, and button, we need a blank row between every table row, just like a space in right, right, and center, so I guess I need to make vertical-align as middle as default.

Comment: So vertical align will not vary and always be middle, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Joey, yeah .. and for multiline items you just need to put `<br>` between `and can be`, `multilined`, and `too`, if those are supposed to be same line, input will be `|and can be multilined too | ....... | ..... | `.

Comment: I think your multi-column cells are ambiguous: the last row shows that text can extend beyond the ASCII art column width, so we cannot use the horizontal alignment of `|`s to judge colspans. Therefore, the 4th and 5th rows could span 1 and 2 columns (as visually, but unreliably indicated) or 2 and 1 columns. [Example](https://hastebin.com/egimunuqob.rb)

Comment: @Adám, thanks for taking a look. Yeah, might be that's the reason there is not much interest on this.

Comment: @YOU Also, this is a very complex challenge, pretty much implementing a large subset of the [Wiki markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki#Editing) for [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Table). Maybe you should narrow the scope by removing all formatting; alignment, borders, headers (these are also ambiguous), and just focusing on converting the `-|` style table into HTML. Maybe even remove the row and column spans?

Comment: I don't remember why I put all those things in, may be similar challenge was there already, for simple tables, but I don't know. I need to look up more.

Comment: @Adám, removed rowspan, colspan, multiline and vertical align. Not sure it could be duplicate entry now.

Comment: @YOU How should we align `|ambiguous|`?

Comment: Also, you need to define "valid HTML", "normal", "bold". And how are table headers indicated?

Comment: |ambiguous| is undefined, so it can be anything. And in 2017, it is too much outdated or boring to do styling on html tables. Can I just leave this thread as is?

Comment: @programmer5000, became duped, because of you guys suggestion. I rollbacked.

Answer (score 5):

I attempted a problem I threw out as [a suggested](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/announcing-the-codegolf-se-first-periodic-premier-programming-puzzle-push/303#303) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) for 1p5.

In c, lex and yacc I needed more than 9600 characters ungolfed (fully commented, errors handled, some debugging code left in place, but some efficiency sacrificed in the name of shorter code), which seems pretty long, but c is about the most pessimal language you could choose for this problem except fortran 77 or something from the Turing Tarpit. The reference implementation can run its own build, which has some of that bootstrapping voodoo.

None-the-less, this is a relatively big project, and I don't want to post it unless people feel it is both well specified and interesting.

As yet there is no validation script, and I am not sure how one could be written as the acceptable output order could be post-order depth first or post-order breadth first and there is a left-first vs. right-first ambiguity on both. What a bother.

*Aside: I'm quite proud of the lex and yacc part of my code, as I consider it spiffy.*

---

### A minimal implementation of the make (1) utility.

By minimal I mean,

- No built in rules, and no pattern or suffix rules.
- No variables and therefore no variable assignment or
  manipulations; also no variable expansion which includes no
  expansion of environment variables.
- No automatic variables like $< and $@.

This only leaves constructs (called rules) of the form

```
<target> ":" <prerequisite>* "\n" ["\t" <action> "\n"]*
```

Where each `<target>` and `<prerequisite>` is a whitespace delimited
string which *may* (or may not) represent a filename. Empty lines
have no effect and "#" marks the beginning of a end of
line comment (the sequence "#[^\n]*\n" should be treated as "\n"
so it does not interfere with rules; this has the side effect of
making "#" illegal in targets, prerequisites and actions). Colons
are prohibited in identifiers.

The program should take its input from the standard input or by
reading a file called "makefile" - implementer's choice. The program then attempts to
"build" every target named on the command line. Any targets
specified on the command line which do not appear in the makefile
and do not represent an existing file should generate an error and cause the program to exit
before execution of any rules. In the event that no target is
named on the command line, default to building the first target
in the input.

Duplicate targets *may* (not must!) be treated as an error.

A target is deemed already built if

1. It names an existing file and
2. All its prerequisites are fulfilled

Otherwise it is built by

1. Building all unfulfilled prerequisites then
2. Running each `<action>` sequentially in the order they appear in the input, 
     and if the action returns an exceptional exit state, stopping the program.

A prerequisite is deemed fulfilled if

- The prerequisite represents an existing file and
- The prerequisite is built and
- The target is "newer" than the (fully built) prerequisite

A target is deemed "older" (i.e. not "newer") than its prerequisite if one of

- Both represent files and the prerequisite has been
     modified more recently than the target.
- The target does not represent an existing file, and the
     prerequisite does.

apply.

Authors on systems which do not support fork/exec semantics may
write a batch file or script which is invoked as the program
terminates, but that script *must* stop on the first
unsuccessful action.

### Sample Input

```
# Babymake compatible makefile for babymake
all:babymake

babymake : lex.yy.o  y.tab.o  babymake.o 
    cc -o babymake lex.yy.o y.tab.o babymake.o

babymake.o : babymake.c babymake.h
    cc -c babymake.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c y.tab.h
    cc -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c : babymake.l
    lex babymake.l

y.tab.o: y.tab.c babymake.h
    cc -c y.tab.c

y.tab.c : babymake.y  
    yacc -d babymake.y

clean:
    rm -f babymake.o  lex.yy.o  y.tab.o

cleaner: clean # just testing end of line comments
    rm -f y.tab.c y.tab.h
    rm -f lex.yy.c

bogus: boguser 
    echo "building bogus" # test in another context
```

### Sample output

```
$ ./babymake < babymake.example cleaner
 rm -f babymake.o  lex.yy.o  y.tab.o
 rm -f y.tab.c y.tab.h
 rm -f lex.yy.c
$ ./babymake < babymake.example all    
 cc -c babymake.c
 yacc -d babymake.y
 cc -c y.tab.c
 lex babymake.l
 cc -c lex.yy.c
 cc -o babymake lex.yy.o y.tab.o babymake.o
$ ./babymake < babymake.example    
$ ./babymake < babymake.example bogus
ERRNO: 2: No such file or directory No rule to make target 'boguser'.
```

Comment: `The program should take it's input from the standard input or by reading a file called "makefile"` - is this a choice for the implementer to make? Or should the program read stdin, and if it's empty then look for `makefile`? `Any targets specified on the command line which do not appear in the makefile and do not represent an existing file should generate an error before execution of any rules.` Does "generate an error" include aborting, such that no rules are executed? `Running each in sequence` - missing "action"? Why is the sample input indented? I'll do an edit for punctuation in a bit.

Comment: In order. (1) Implementer's choice. Should be more specific. (2) Generate an error means abort; this is a unix utility after all. (3) The sample is indented because I made a strenuous effort to get the tabs in, and MarkDown just doesn't like tabs. Also there is a new sample input that has some comments in.

Comment: More questions: 1) `The target is "newer" than the prerequisite once *they* have been fulfilled.` What does this mean? Should this text be talking about building? 2) Under what circumstances can a target be built twice?

Comment: 1) Yes and 2) Standard `make` never builds a target twice, and neither does my reference implementation. But I should probably say that it is or is not allowed. Do you have a feeling in the matter?

Comment: Saying that it is not allowed is probably best. Otherwise there's potential for stuff to go wrong when multiple targets depend on `clean`, which will never be built because it doesn't correspond to a file.

Comment: I suggest that the golf exercise be to simply output the list of commands to run, not actually execute them. Will make testing much easier.

Comment: This is awesome. But I'm too mystified by make to even fathom how it goes about it. I'd never be able to do this without stealing ideas from other posts on the page. But then, I'm an introverted intuitive, intellectuals would probbly have an easier time. :) I haven't checked, but .. I say it's ready to post. Answers may be slow in coming, but *they WILL come!*

Comment: @luserdroog my reference implementation builds a directed graph (in the technical sense) of dependencies and then starts evaluating from the named target(s). I can't recall right off if I enforced acycality on the graph or not. I believe that real make insists on it.

Comment: That doesn't semm quite so unfathomable. I suppose the variables and impicit rules are responsible for much of the mystery.

Comment: This has been inactive for five years. If you're not going to post it, may I?

Comment: @MDXF I think I'd rather post this one myself, but it may be a few days.

Answer (score 5):

## [Line up for golf!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115234/line-up-for-golf)

Comment: The comments in the test cases reduce their usefulness as test cases. Moreover, the first one contradicts the "full specification", and the second one adds to it. The spec should contain everything needed to justify the correctness of the test cases. You also need to specify desired behaviour when there is no solution, and to include a test case for that scenario.

Comment: How  are conditionals to be interpreted when mixed in a single full condition? `Alice is 1st or 1st to last and in front Bob or 1 space behind Bob`

Comment: This seems like a good challenge, but Peter Taylor and Jan Dvorak's concerns should be addressed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Edited, but how does the first one contradict?

Comment: @JanDvorak Edited to clarify.

Comment: Another concern: What if there is no solution? What if there is more than one?

Comment: Please delete this now that it is posted.

Answer (score 5):

## The smallest circles

---

**Challenge**

This is a variant of the smallest-circle problem, but instead of one circle, you get three. Given a list of coordinates, output three circles such that the following conditions are met:

1. Each input coordinate must be located inside or on the perimeter of a circle.
2. The sum of the radii of all three circles must be minimal.
3. The coordinates and radii of all three circles must be non-negative integers.

You must place all three circles. You may place overlapping circles. A circle with a radius of zero that is directly on top of an input coordinate is considered to be covering that input coordinate.

**Input**

A list containing between 1 and 1000 pairs of integers, inclusive. Each pair of integers represents an xy-coordinate. Use whatever input format you want to use.

For example, the input...

> 1,1;1,2;2,2;3,3

... can be drawn like this:

[image]

**Output**

A list of three integer triples. Each triple contains an x coordinate, followed by a y coordinate, followed by a radius. The triples, and the integers within each triple, must be distinguishable from one another. Otherwise, the output format is not important.

Example:

> 1,1,1;2,2,1;3,3,2

Given this example output, circles would be drawn at (1,1), (2,2), and (3,3). The first two circles would have a radius of 1, and the third would have a radius of 2. The sum of the radii would be 4.

**Test case explained**

Given the input...

> 1,1;1,2;2,2;3,3

... you could output...

> 1,2,1;3,3,0;0,0,0

... or you could output...

> 1/2/1
> 3/3/0
> 0/0/0

The radii sums to 1, and since it is not possible to draw three circles whose radii sum to less than 1 that encompass or touch all four points, this is the correct answer.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) (maybe [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) too)

Comment: The text says that the list is colon-delimited, but the example is semicolon-delimited. It would help readability to mention that you can place *three* circles at some point before "*The sum of the radii of all three circles is minimal*". It's not clear whether the coordinates and radii of the circles must be integers, nor whether the radii must be non-zero. Finally, some test cases would be nice.

Comment: If I didn't fully address any of the comments above please let me know.

Comment: If the input can contain up to 1000 points it might help to have a large test case too.

Comment: For large numbers of input points, how will you assess whether the output is of minimal total radius? Is a proof required or is it sufficient that no other answer/person can find a counterexample? You could also have a judge program / reference implementation to define the correct total radius.

Comment: @trichoplax Hopefully I'll have a reference implementation before I post. If I decide that I am too lazy for that, then I will assume answers are correct until someone finds a counterexample. I will come up with a larger test case.

Comment: Does the rigid I/O format really add anything interesting to the challenge? http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/8478

Comment: @MartinBüttner I completely relaxed the input format, and I somewhat relaxed the output format. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Rainbolt If I read the output section right, you're allowing any distinguishable delimiters for the output now? Then it might be clearer if one of the two example formats didn't use commas as the inner delimiter (maybe use spaces for the second example or so).

Comment: The rewrite states two conditions which must be met, but there's a third one hidden down in the output section: that the coordinates and radii must be integers. That should be up in the first section.

Answer (score 5):

### Verification of solutions to the 3 knishops problem

For the purposes of this question, a **knishop** is a fairy chess piece which can move to precisely those squares which are not an integer distance away. So knight moves (distance $\sqrt{5}$) are ok, as are bishop moves (non-zero multiples of $\sqrt(2)$) and many more besides.

The [3 knishops problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/6636/228) is to place 3 knishops on an infinite chessboard such that none of them attack each other, but every square other than the 3 they occupy is attacked by at least one of them. A more prosaic formulation is to find three lattice points which form an [Erdős-Diophantine graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Diophantine_graph).

Your task is to write code (see below) which takes three co-ordinates as input and produces a [truthy or falsy output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/194): truthy if the co-ordinates are a solution to the 3 knishops problem, and falsy otherwise. The code must be able to handle each of the test cases below in no more than one minute on a reasonable desktop machine.

#### The small print

"Write code" should be understood to permit one of the following:

- A program which takes input via stdin and gives output via stdout. The permitted input formats are 6 integers, delimited by your choice of a comma or whitespace, and optionally wrapped in one of parentheses `()`, curly brackets `{}`, or square brackets `[]`; or three pairs, each pair similarly delimited and wrapped, and the pairs similarly delimited and wrapped. Examples:

  ```
  0 0 3 4 12 13
  (0,0,3,4,12,13)
  {0,0},{3,4},{12,13}
  {{0 0} {3 4} {12 13}}
  [{0 0} {3 4} {12 13}]
  ```

  Or using different whitespace for the two types of delimiter:

  ```
  0 0
  3 4
  12 13
  ```
- A named function, verb, block, or equivalent which takes input as an array of six values, an array of three two-element arrays, three separate arrays of two-element arrays, or six separate parameters; and gives output as a return value.

You may assume that none of the input values or the unattacked points have coordinates outside the range $\pm 2^30$.

#### Test cases

```
input                          output

(0 0) (0 0) (0 0)              false
(0 0) (3 4) (12 13)            false
(5 -5) (8 -1) (2 -9)           false
(0 0) (384 2030) (720 1653)    true
```

TODO More test cases.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

---

NB I need to code up some naïve approaches and test whether the one-minute restriction is actually relevant. I'm hoping that MathJAX will be enabled; if not, the stuff in dollars will be replaced before posting.

Answer (score 5):

## Fortnightly Challenge #4 - Data Structures

**[Join us in the Fortnightly Challenge Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20517/fortnightly-challenge-of-2015-01-23-data-structures) to work out the details of this challenge!**

Imagine square coloured blocks where each side can be connected to another block, allowing you to move or rotate connected blocks as one. Let's call a collection of such blocks, all connected to each other either directly or indirectly, a *group*.

Your task is to simulate these blocks via a number of commands which you must implement.

## Commands

All input commands will be given one per line (via STDIN), and likewise all query outputs should one per line (via STDOUT).

- `place <x> <y> <colour>`: Place a block with a given colour at the specified coordinates.
- `remove <x> <y>`: Remove the block at the specified coordinates, deleting any connections with it.
- `connect <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>`: Connect two adjacent blocks.
- `disconnect <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>`: Disconnect two adjacent blocks.
- `count`: Count the number of groups and print the result.
- `move <x> <y> <dx> <dy>`: Move the entire group containing the specified block by the given offset.
- `rotate <x> <y> <times anticlockwise>`: Rotate the entire group containing the specified block anticlockwise about said block by some number (guaranteed to be either 1, 2 or 3) of times
- `connected <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>`: Print `y` if blocks exist at the two given coordinates and they are in the same group, or `n` otherwise.
- `nearest <x> <y>`: Print the nearest block to the given coordinate by Manhattan distance (difference in x-coordinate + difference in y-coordinate), in the form `<x> <y> <colour>`. If there are no placed blocks, print `none`. If there is more than one closest block, print any.
- `colour <colour>`: Print all block coordinates with the given colour, each space-separated and of the form `(<x>, <y>)`. If there are no such blocks, print `none`.
- `halt`: Terminate the program

### Errors

Commands will always be given with the correct number and type of arguments. However sometimes an operation doesn't make sense, for example:

- Placing a block where a block already exists
- Removing, connecting, disconnecting, moving or rotating non-existent blocks
- Connect or disconnecting blocks which are already connected or disconnected
- Move or rotate commands which end up with two blocks overlapping (with emphasis that only the final state matters — groups which are rotated 2 or 3 times do not need to check for overlaps after each rotation)

If any of the above occur, print `Error: <command>`. For example, if there is no block at `0,0`, then the command `remove 0 0` will result in

```
Error: remove 0 0
```

Note that queries should never result in an error.

## Scoring

There will be six types of test cases:

1. A test which is biased towards `place/remove` commands
2. A test which is biased towards `connect/disconnect/count/connected` commands
3. A test which is biased towards `move/rotate` commands
4. A test which is biased towards `nearest` commands
5. A test which is biased towards `colour` commands
6. An all-rounder test

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the goal is to make your program process the commands as quickly as possible. A leaderboard will be kept for each type of test,, and the winner will be the user with the lowest sum of placements over all tests (e.g. if you came 1st, 3rd, 2nd, 2nd, 3rd, 4th then your score is `1 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 15`).

The tests and test generator can be found on [this Github page](https://github.com/Sp3000/Fortnightly4), along with a unit tester which will be run for each submission to ensure correctness.

## Rules/clarifications

- To prevent cluttering the leaderboard, each user may provide at most **one** submission
- No multithreading or parallel processing
- Use no more than 2GB of RAM — this rule is not strictly enforced, but horribly space-inefficient solutions may be disqualified
- No third party libraries (standard libraries are OK)
- All coordinates are guaranteed to fit into a 32-bit int, and all colours are alphanumeric strings

## Example

*(in progress)*

[image]

Comment: 2. Lego pieces/attachable cubes

Comment: 5. Controller-mediated build-your-own data structure

Comment: A. Lego pieces.

Comment: B. Attachable unit cubes (for simplicity)

Comment: Winning criteria:

Comment: I. Code golf (fewest bytes)

Comment: II. Fastest algorithm

Comment: III. Something else (leave a comment below)

Comment: Number of cube structures:

Comment: 1. Exactly one structure

Comment: 2. Any number of structures

Comment: Connections/adjacency:

Comment: A. Connections should be explicitly given via a function call

Comment: B. Each cube is connected to the cube it was built off

Comment: C. Each cube automatically connects to all of its neighbours

Comment: Moving to 2D might simplify rotations greatly, while retaining enough complexity to be worth a challenge.

Comment: Is there min/max values for the coordinates?

Comment: @stokastic Hmm good question... I'm thinking maybe 32-bit int range?

Answer (score 5):

## Write a Connect Four Bot

---

Your task is to write a Connect Four bot. Your submission must be less than 2000 bytes long. You may not save state. You may not use libraries or external resources that are, at my discretion, related to Connect Four.

**Gameplay**

Your submission will play against each other submission one hundred times. Each player will play first for exactly half of the matches. Each match flows like:

1. Player 1 drops a red token into a column.
2. If Player 1 has not won, then Player 2 drops a black token into a column.
3. If Player 2 has not won, repeat.

Tokens fall down a column until they collide with another token in the row beneath it or hit the bottom of the board. Your program will be terminated and called anew after each move. You win the match if you connect four tokens vertically, horizontally or diagonally.

The winner of the challenge is the submission with the most match wins at the end of a tournament.

**Input**

The first command line argument you will receive is the game board. Rows are `;` delimited . Cells are `,` delimited. The first row is the top of the board. A cell contains `0` if unoccupied, `1` if occupied by Player 1, and `2` if occupied by Player 2. The board you receive will always be 7 columns by 6 row.

The second command line argument you will receive is your player number. That means `1` or `2`.

Examples:

> java ThatBot 0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0;0,2,1,0;0,1,2,1 1

**Output**

You will print the column for which you would like to move to STDOUT. Columns are zero indexed. The following earns an immediate loss:

- Dropping a token into a full column
- Dropping a token into a column that does not exist
- Failing to output anything to STDOUT within one second

**Deliverables**

You must submit the following:

- A program
- A unique name
- A method of calling your program via command line
- Any instructions I might need to compile your program. I'll try my best, but my best isn't always good enough.

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Comment: Oops, didn't see that, sorry :S I think there might be problems still, as several moves could be hard-coded in. (i.e. the first move(s) is always just the middle column)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I am totally fine with a few hard coded moves, but perhaps I should reintroduce the byte limit that I originally had in place. Do you think 500 characters is sufficient? I went ahead and added it back. I also added a restriction on external resources to prevent external hard coding. It's probably a loophole, but one worth covering I think. (I'm in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) btw if you want to discuss.)

Comment: 500 seems fine, but it might squeeze Java / C# entries. I'll see how long a pretty bad bot is over the weekend if you haven't posted yet ;p

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It will be a little while. I haven't written the controller yet. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I took a [program that claims to do perfect play](http://tromp.github.io/c4/c4.html) and added some timing: the vast majority of its moves take less than 1ms; in about 1 game in 8 it has a single move which takes more than 1s. The longest I've seen was just short of 2s, so with a bit of optimisation and a more modern computer it might well come inside the 1s limit. The byte limit would hit it hard, though: its opening book is 12k.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for that. Knowing what you just found out, do you think that the 500 byte limit plus the timing restriction are enough to make the challenge interesting? If someone can solve Connect Four optimally under those restrictions, then at least PPCG has created something worth having, right? I'm just asking because nobody has upvoted the sandbox proposal, so I assume that maybe there are still some concerns about it.

Comment: I got distracted by looking for work on perfect play and didn't post the thoughts I had. I'm slightly confused about the input format: is `\n` a literal backslash followed by an n, or does it mean a newline character? The latter would be my assumption, but the example input makes it look literal (and wouldn't work if it were newline). I don't think you specify whether the output assumes 0-indexed or 1-indexed columns. I'm not sure whether the rule about external resources is intended to indicate that I can fetch stuff from the web without it counting towards the byte limit.

Comment: I feel that with a strict byte limit, you're most likely to see mainly versions of min/max or other "simple" algorithms. If you want more interesting or varied players, you may want to relax it. Banning extensive hard-coding is good, but I'd hate for it to come at the expense of creativity.

Comment: The byte limit and timing restriction between them may be too much: I can't see any approach which attempts a real analysis fitting into 500 bytes except in a golfing language which will struggle with the time limit. Maybe 2kB would be a better compromise.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 2000 bytes it shall be, then. I changed the row delimiter to `;` to eliminate confusion. I added that columns are zero indexed. The rule about external resources was intended to allow you to fetch from existing resources, but to disallow you to fetch from resources that were created after the fact. In hindsight, this might open the door to abuse, so I've removed that allowance. I'm unsure if this leaves the challenge vulnerable or not, so I'll bring it up in chat.

Comment: Discussed in chat and made the change. I think I've addressed all comments up to now.

Comment: I didn't look very closely at that command line. It should be `java MyBot` (or maybe `java -classpath c:\ MyBot`, not `java C:\MyBot.java`. Other that that, looks good.

Answer (score 5):

## The Virtual Prisoners [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

#### Background

The year is 2251. You are a self-evolving KOTH bot, in the mysterious land known as Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. To evolve, you need permissions, and to get permissions, you need reputation. You decide that the best way to do this is to take over all of the questions to gain as much reputation as possible. The only problem? Every other bot has decided to do the exact same thing.

#### Game Explanation

Each round is battled on a question, with 11 vote nodes, between you and your enemy. The board starts as this:

```
A1 A2 A3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8 B9 B10 B11
```

`A` is player A's nodes, `B` is player B's nodes, and `N` is a neutral node.
Each turn, you may:

- Vote on a vote node. If both players vote, nothing happens. If one side votes:

  - and the node is controlled by no-one (neutral), it becomes that side's.
  - and it is controlled by the voter's enemy, it becomes neutral.
  - and it is controlled by the voter, nothing happens.
- Guard a vote node. This guards the node from votes (friendly or enemy) for 2 turns.
- Use your 'power'. The powers are listed below, including how to use them.

Your side wins if it controls at least 2/3rds (66%) of the vote nodes.

10000 rounds will be run, and the winner of the KOTH is whichever bot has the most wins (in the event of a tie, or indeterminate outcome, more matches are run until a clear winner is decided.)

#### How Your Bot Should Work

It should accept as command-line arguments:
`B A1 A2 A3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8 B9 B10 B11`
Where `A` denotes Player A's nodes, `N` denotes a neutral node, `B` denotes Player B's nodes, and the first argument (`B` in this case) is the player your bot is. (This is decided randomly, your bot should work regardless.)
It should return one of the following (powers are general rules):

- `V-4`, vote on node 4
- `G-3`, guard node 3
- `P-N`, use power 'Neutralize'
  with or without a trailing newline.

  #### Powers

  Intended to give bots a small boost. If `X` was your power, you would use `P-X`. You may only have one power per bot.
- `N` - Neutralize: Turn 2 random nodes to neutral ones.
- `R` - Rebellion: Pick a random node, and randomly turn it to a friendly, neutral, or hostile node.
- `S` - Swift Strikes: Pick two random nodes, and vote on them.

**Here are the extra rules:**

- The bots must fully run offline.
- The bots may not attempt to read any files, including their own source code.
- The bots may not tamper with, hack, or destroy other bots.
- The bots must return one of the three commands (`V`, `G`, or `P`). If they do not, they forfeit their turn.
- The bots must not be targeting other bots specifically. (Beating general strategies is welcome.)
- You may update your bot as often as you like, but bots that are updated very frequently with no good reason (i.e, fixing fatal errors is a good reason) will be disqualified.
- Your bot must take under 90 seconds for it's turn. If it takes longer, it will be disqualified.

#### Submission contents

Your submission **must** contain:

- The code for the bot
- The language it is written in (and a link to an offline interpreter, if necessary)
- Your bot's name (for the leaderboards)
- How to compile and run your bot

If you do not include all of the required items in your submission, you will be notified, but your bot may not compete until this is fixed.

#### Example Match

Matches are organized between 2 randomly-selected bots. Here is an example, with bots `A` and `B`:
The board begins as this:

```
A1 A2 A3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8 B9 B10 B11
```

Bot A makes his move, voting on `N4`, then Bot B votes on `N5`:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 B5 N6 N7 N8 B9 B10 B11
```

Node 4 becomes `A4`, and it is now controlled by Bot A. Likewise, node 5 becomes `B5`.

`A` votes on `N8`, and so does `B`:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 B5 N6 N7 N8 B9 B10 B11
```

Why did nothing happen? That's because both bots voted on the same node - cancelling out each other's effects.

When one bot controls 66% or greater of the nodes, that bot gains a win and the other bot gains a loss.

The game ends after 1024 turns, to prevent any bots that wait around forever. Whoever has the most nodes afterwards wins, or a draw if they have the same amount.

### Additional Notes

- I will be submitting an example bot written in Python as part of my challenge. You are free to use and modify this bot for your submission.
- If your bot gives invalid output (not of the form `C-A`, where `C` is the command and `A` is the argument), the bot forfeits its turn. If it does, you will be notified, and your bot will be removed until it is fixed.

### Meta Questions and Notes

- Are there any loopholes?
- Should I add/modify/delete some of the powers?
- Is something too simple/confusing/uninteresting/overpowered?
- Should bots be able to see which nodes are and are not guarded?
- Should I limit people to one bot? If not, I will prevent the same person's bots from battling each other.
- I have thought of the following alternative way to win matches:

  - The game lasts 1024 turns. Whoever has the most nodes at the end wins.
  - If, at one point, one bot controls all 11 nodes, that bot automatically wins.
- Would this be a better win condition?

Comment: I have a few questions. 1) If I make a new node, will it be neutral? 2) How are the matches organized? If there are, say, 5 submissions, does each pair have a separate battle, after which you count victories, or do they somehow work in teams (as the title suggests)? 3) With some strategies it may be that the game runs forever. You should probably add a time limit (some `N` turns), after which the game automatically ends in a draw, or a win for the player controlling the most nodes.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks for your feedback! I've included a section on how the game works.

Comment: Could you add C# (or .NET in general?)

Comment: @LegionMammal978 How do you install that on Linux? The list is mostly because I can't run a lot of things like GolfScript, but I'd be glad to, if you can tell me where to find it.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI you could use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin). I'm mainly just looking for C#.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Oh, OK. Turns out I installed it for an earlier purpose, thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not complete, but [this question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1213/194) has instructions for running a number of languages.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the link!

Comment: Maybe add a clock time limit for each turn, so bots don't simply run an endless loop blocking you running the simulation?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I'll watch each of the simulations (with output on what the bots are doing), and any bot that takes too long is disqualified.

Answer (score 5):

## Bitstring Family Trees

This challenge is reproduced from memory and my own solution, from a challenge that was posted in the job-application section of http://itasoftware.com before they were bought by Google. I reached out to ITA and Google a few years ago, after the acquisition, to ask to re-post this here (and on codegolf.com when it existed) and never heard back from them.

A bitstring is a string of 1s and 0s. Bitstrings reproduce asexually through a mutation-prone process, producing a child that is a copy of its parent but with each bit flipped with 25% probability. Starting with a list containing one bitstring, we repeatedly select one bitstring from the list at random, produce its child, and add that child to the list. This produces a list of bitstrings, each of which (except the first) has somewhere earlier in the list a parent from which it was mutated.

Now, the challenge. Your program will be presented with a list of bitstrings produced as described above, but the order of the list will be shuffled. You are to calculate the least improbable family tree for the given bitstrings. If there are two or more such trees, choose any of them.

Your input can be in any useful format, including as a list/array of lists/strings as a function parameter or in a variable, already existing on the stack for a stack based language, or from stdin with delimiters but not operators, so four four-bit strings might be "1010\n1001\n1011\n0010" or "[1010,1001,1011,0010]" or even "4 1010100110110010".

Your output can be in any unambiguous format. The canonical format is a list of integers, where the nth integer in the list is the index of the nth provided bitstring's parent in the original list, and a sentinel value for the root entry. Another acceptable form could be an actual tree data structure. Either of these might be returned from a function, printed to stdout, left in a variable, or left on the stack of a stack based language.

The above two provisions should be interpreted with the context that this challenge is not about golfing the input and output code. It's about golfing the algorithmic logic.

For the example input above of 1010,1001,1011,0010 the most likely family tree is that the first entry is the root, the last two are children of the first, and the second is a child of the third, all three mutations involving a single bit flip out of four bits.

With the challenge I will provide a few data sets of different sizes (10 10-bit strings, 100 100-bit strings, maybe bigger) with their solutions.

Comment: Could you give a more precise definition of 'most likely'?

Comment: If two family trees are equally likely, can either be output, or would you prefer a rule to specify which one must be output?

Comment: Would it be interesting to have the 25% probability provided as an input `p`, or would keeping the parameter fixed allow for more golfing opportunities?

Comment: @feersum I'm not sure what you mean. Highest probability? Least improbable?

Comment: @trichoplax I hadn't considered that. I guess I'd accept either. I'll mention that. The probability in the original question was 20%, but I think a non-repeating decimal in base 2 will be much more golf-friendly.

Comment: With respect to @feersum's question, I see at least two subtleties. Firstly, what assumption should be made about the distribution of the initial bitstring? Secondly, the "family tree" isn't in bijection with the sequence of random selections. The first one needs to be addressed explicitly; the second is probably best addressed with a worked example which calculates the probabilities for each possible sequence and then sums them over the family tree corresponding to each sequence. As an additional point, an important corner case will be one where the bitstrings aren't all distinct.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The initial bitstring is a sequence of bits chosen independently and uniformly at random. I am unclear on your second point. Do you mean that it's possible for the family tree produced at random to not be the one most likely to have produced a given result set? That makes sense, but seems obvious. I can work out the 4x4 example by hand with probabilities for each of the 6 possible family trees, if that would clarify things?

Comment: I agree that it's obvious, but it is often a good idea to state the obvious, because otherwise it can be overlooked. For example, it's also obvious that the 4x4 example must have more than 4! = 24 possible family trees... (I think it's 64 possible trees, so maybe that was just a typo).

Answer (score 5):

I nearly posted this without sandboxing, but thought it was perhaps too trivial - comments welcome.  <strike>I was considering perhaps making it [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) too with no digits `[0-9]` in the source code.</strike>Done.

## Golf the numbers round a dartboard

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

For those of you not familiar with [the game of darts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts), a standard dartboard looks like this:
[image]

This challenge is simple - output the sequence of numbers starting from `20` moving in a clockwise direction:

`20 1 18 4 13 6 10 15 2 17 3 19 7 16 8 11 14 9 12 5`

To make it a bit more interesting, the digits `[0-9]` may not appear anywhere in your source code.

- Your entry must not accept any input and it must output this list in exactly this order.
- The formatting of the list output may be whatever is convenient for your language.
- You must not use any builtins designed explicitly to generate this sequence.

OEIS fans may like to note that this is sequence [has an entry](https://oeis.org/A003833).

Comment: I like the restricted source version

Comment: @TimmyD Link added.  I'm surprised we don't have an OEIS tag - I guess it wouldn't really add much.

Comment: @ quintopia - yes, I think that's probably the way to go - edited.

Comment: I was able to do this in CJam in 26 bytes using character to int conversion (it only didn't work online for 13 because it's character is carriage return.) Should this be allowed? http://goo.gl/JxEcjo . Also, in CJam 1,2,3 and 10-20 are single letter constants. Should those be allowed?

Comment: @geokavel yes, and yes.

Comment: This is just asking for string compression, especially since digits can't be used even indirectly.

Comment: @xnor to discourage that, maybe restrict entries to printable ASCII (or give a bonus of *log 95/log 256 for using only printable ASCII)?

Answer (score 5):

## Verify a game of Morpion Solitaire

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)

[Morpion Solitaire](http://www.morpionsolitaire.com/English/Rules.htm) is an interesting, unsolved "single-player game". (The linked site lists several variants - we're talking about 5T here.) It has been proven that solving or even approximating it is NP-hard. But we're going to do something simpler here: your challenge will be to verify whether the game has been played correctly.

The rules are fairly simple. You start on a regular (infinite) grid, with 36 intersections marked in the following shape:

[image]

Now a move consists of drawing a straight line segment, orthogonally or 45 degrees with the grid, through four marked and one unmarked intersection. The unmarked intersection will then be marked for future moves:

[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]

The lines may cross or touch, but they must never overlap (notice that the last move shares an endpoint in a straight line with an earlier move, but does not overlap with it). The goal of the game is to make as many move as possible. [The world record](http://www.morpionsolitaire.com/English/RecordsGrids5T.htm) is at 178 moves.

Because the grid gets very messy after a while, it becomes very hard to reconstruct a game. People work around this problem, by writing consecutive numbers into the intersections they add. However, even when this is not done, it is always possible to verify the validity of game.

**Further reading:**

- [Morpion Solitaire](http://www.morpionsolitaire.com/): the full page the rules link was taken from. Beware of iframes.
- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_Five): note that this uses a different initial setup.

### The Challenge

You're given an ASCII representation of a played game of Morpion Solitaire (the game may or may not be finished). Every other cell represents an intersection, which can be either unmarked (`.`), one of the initial intersections (`o`) or one of the intersections added by a move (`#`). All other cells are either spaces, or one of `-`, `|`, `/`, `\`, `X` indicating that a line-segment was drawn across the two adjacent intersections. The example above would look like this:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . .

. . . . o-o-o-o-# . . .
        |/     /       
. . . . o . . o . . . .
       /|    /         
. . . # o . # o . . . .
     /  |  /           
. o-o-o-o-# . o o o o .
   /    |/             
. o . . # . . . . . o .
        |              
. o . . # . . . . . o .
        |              
. o o o o . . o o o o .
        |              
. . . . o . . o . . . .
        |              
. . . . o . . o . . . .

. . . . o o o o . . . .

. . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Output a truthy value if the game represented by graph can be played by following the rules, and a falsy value otherwise.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

You may assume that the initial intersections always form the cross shape displayed above (although I doubt any answers will be affected by this).

Your code should solve any of the test **in less than 5 seconds**. This should not be an issue as very efficient solutions exist.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Sandbox Notes

- Will add test cases...

Comment: The simplest representation for parsing would be to give either the endpoints of each line as cartesian coordinates, or one endpoint and a direction (either one of 8 directions, or it could be standardized to one of 4 directions if the N/E/NE/NW is always the endpoint given.) Checking would then be fairly straightforward: start with the empty grid and see which lines are allowed, until all are exhausted.

Comment: The ASCII art representation will require more effort for parsing: I *think* it's unambiguous because you can identify endpoints by looking for for intersections which don't have opposite pairs of `|_\/`, but it could take quite a few parses through the file. You would also need some way of identifying the start points.

Comment: @steveverrill There will be no information about endpoints in the input. In a finished game (without numbering) you only have individual line segments (four of which make up a move). That's why I think an ASCII representation is simpler than a graph, where you need to piece together manually which edges form a straight line of four segments. I also think an ASCII representation doesn't necessarily need to be parsed at all: I think it can be solved straight via manipulation of the character grid (in fact, this should be doable in Retina).

Comment: 1. It would be clearer to talk about drawing a straight line *segment* through 4 marked and one unmarked lattice point, as "straight line" often implies that it's infinite. 2. It seems that the lines must be axis-aligned or at 45 degrees to the axis. If so, it would be good to state that explicitly in the description of play. 3. The page linked in the first sentence is very uninformative. I assume you did it because the diagrams on the Wikipedia page are for a different initial setup, but there must be some better external link.

Comment: In that case I would go for the ASCII art representation. It also depends to some extent on which is the most convenient way for you to obtain / generate test cases.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, I'll edit those suggestion in. As for the page I linked, did you see the navigation in the left iframe? (I overlooked that at first.) I'll link to Wikipedia as well though.

Comment: I agree with Peter that the website is a bit of a mess. There are many variations of the game, so I think you should state that this is the 5T variant (identified by the fact that Christopher Rosin holds the records for 5T at 178 moves and 5D at 82 moves.) It took me a while to work out why Marc Bertin at 216 moves in 1974 was not the record holder: (He was playing 5T+.)  Only the 5T (endpoints of parallel lines touching allowed) and 5D (endpoints of parallel lines must be disjoint) variants are unsolved according to the website.

Comment: The person who wrote that site needs to be dragged kicking and screaming into the 21st century. But I'd prefer a link to http://www.morpionsolitaire.com/English/Rules.htm and the navigation be damned than a link to the front page.

Answer (score 5):

## Four-Byte Bloom Filter

[Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) are cool.  In the words of that Wikipedia article:

> A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure, conceived by Burton Howard Bloom in 1970, that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not, thus a Bloom filter has a 100% recall rate. In other words, a query returns either "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set".

The motivation behind Bloom filters is that, by giving up perfect accuracy, the amount of memory necessary can be dramatically decreased.

A Bloom filter takes the form of a set of bits, along with a set of hash functions.  To insert something into the Bloom filter, calculate the N different hashes and flip those bits to 1.

```
initialization 
00000000

letter `P` maps to 1 when using hash function F and 6 when using hash function G
01000010
```

Additional elements are added over top previous ones.

```
letter `h` maps to 6 and 4
01001010
```

To test if an element is a member of a set, perform the hashes and check to see if those bits are 1.  If not all of them are 1, then it can't possibly be a member of the set.  If they are all 1s, then it could be a member.

```
letter `W` maps to 0 and 4
01001010
^   ^
`W` is not a member

letter `P` maps to 1 and 6
01001010
 ^    ^
`P` could be a member (it is)

letter `i` maps to 4 and 1
01001010
 ^  ^
`i` could be a member (it is a false positive)
```

As more elements are added to the set, the probability of false positives increases.  In large-scale applications, a Bloom filter with a small error rate is still an order of magnitude smaller than an exact database.  Below is a neat diagram from [this](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/probabilistic-structures-web-analytics-data-mining/) great article on probabilistic data structures.

[image]

---

In this challenge, you will implement a miniature Bloom filter.  A really, really small Bloom filter with 32 bits.  Your data type will be the 94 non-whitespace printable ASCII characters.

**Functionality**

The Bloom filter will have 32 bits and 2 hash functions.  It is up to you what those two hash functions are, they simply must be decently independent of one another. (Sandbox note, should I specify the hash functions?).  Your program will be asked to do two separate tasks:

- Given a current state of the bloom filter and a list of characters, add those characters to the filter and output the new filter state
- Given a current state of the bloom filter and a list of characters, test those characters for membership and output a list of truthy (could be a member) or falsey (definitely not a member) values.

**Formatting specifics**

Input consists of the current state, an operation, and a list of characters.  The Bloom filter state will be represented as a string of 8 hexadecimal characters.  This will then be followed by either `+` for adding or `?` for membership testing.  Finally, there will be a list of between 1 and 94 characters (printable non-whitespace ASCII) as data points.

Output will either be the new state, as 8 hex characters, or a list of truthy/falsey values.

### Example I/O

```
This represents adding the characters in my username to a blank filter
00000000+PhiNotPi
This is a possible output (7 bits have been permanently flipped)
48a01030

This represent adding the character 1 to the current filter
48a01030+1
This is a possible output (9 bits flipped so far)
48a01074

This represents testing for membership of Phi
48a01074?Phi
Output must be all true since they were added in earlier
[True, True, True]

This represents testing for membership of 12345
48a01074?1234
Output must be true for 1, but not necessarily false for the others
[True, False, False, True, False]
```

Comment: You should specify the hashing function, if you don't want the hashing function is a `mod 32` or worse, `return 4`.

Answer (score 5):

## The largest convex polygon

Given an input of at least one coordinate pair on the Cartesian plane, determine the largest number of sides a convex, non-self-intersecting polygon formed from those points can have.

A convex polygon is a polygon such that there is an angle strictly less than 180˚ and greater than 0˚ between each pair of consecutive sides. Note that if three points are collinear, they still only form one side. Two sides cannot have a 180˚ angle between them.

The ordinate and abscissa of a coordinate are not necessarily integers, and they can be positive, negative, or zero.

If there are less than 3 points, or if the points inputted cannot form a convex polygon, the program should output `0`.

**Test cases**

```
(0,0) (1,1) (3,4)
==> 3

(0,0) (-1,-1) (5,5)
==> 0

(-1,0) (1,0) (0,1) (5,5) (-5,5) (0,-5)
==> 3

(-3,2) (4,6) (-1,2) (0,4) (5,-3) (-2,-2) (1,1)
==> 5

(0,0) (10,0) (10,10) (9,1) (10,4) (9,6) (5,4)
==> 5
```

Here are pictures for the test cases, in order. Note that solutions are not necessarily unique. (Made with Geogebra)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the third test case, can't you get a four-side polygon (-5,5) -- (5,5) -- (1,0) -- (-1,0) -- (-5,5)? (or (0,-5) -- (-1,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,-5))

Comment: @David Thanks for catching that. I will fix it tomorrow,

Comment: This could probably use some more test cases where the result is not the convex hull... if possible even one where none of the points of the convex hull are part of the solution.

Comment: @MartinBüttner The last test case is not the convex hull, as `(10,0)` and `(10,10)` are not included in the output polygon.

Comment: @TimmyD The emphasis in my sentence was on "more". ;) (I admit that may not have been obvious.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I read it as "This could probably use some more test cases, [such as] where the result is not the convex hull" ... yay, English.

Comment: @TimmyD I like ambiguity more than most people.

Answer (score 5):

### Can the robotic arm reach itself?

<s>( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) title is kinda sketch at the moment</s>

A robotic arm is made up of a set of line segments, each with a positive integer length.  Each joint on the robot has two possible positions: **straight or 90 degrees clockwise**.

Here is a robotic arm with 4 line segments of sizes 4, 2, 3, 2

```
+---+-+--+-+
```

Here is the same robot arm with one joint bent

```
+---+-+
      |
      |
      +
      |
      +
```

(vertical scale is kinda messed up)

Right now, the robotic arm isn't reaching itself.  By bending all of the segments, however, the arm can reach itself.

```
+X--+
 |  |
 +--+
```

So, a robotic arm of size `[4,2,3,2]` can reach itself.

Here is a robotic arm of size [3,1,4,3] that can't reach itself:

```
+--++---+--+

+
|
|+--+
+---+
```

Whereas a robotic arm of size [1,1,2,2,3] can reach itself.

```
++-+-+--+

+
X++
| |
+-+
```

A robotic arm of size [2,2,3,5,3,4] can also reach itself

```
a-b-c--d----e--f---g

e--f
|  |
|  |
|a-b
|  g
d--c
```

### Challenge

Given list of numbers, such as `[1,2,3,4,5]`, output a truthy value of the robotic arm can reach itself and a falsey value if it cannot.

Comment: `s/touch/intersect/g`?

Comment: We've had some related challenges I think. At least http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45059/8478

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49713/8478

Comment: The scenario reminds me of [stretchy snakes kissing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53713/20260). Except, these snakes are unusually rigid ... you know what, never mind.

Comment: The first few examples would be clearer if either you also used letters to distinguish the joints or if you at least marked one end of the chain in both the straight and the folded representation.

Comment: You could probably also use more than one example where self-intersection only happens when not all joints are bent like the `[1,1,2,2,3]` example. If that's possible it would be good to have one where you need to bend joints on both sides of a straight joint to make the self-intersection happen, but I don't know if that can happen.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman `s/touch/reach/g`

Comment: Is `4,2,3,3` truthy or falsy?

Comment: Can the robotic arm go *through* itself? The [2,2,3,5,3,4]  case seems to indicate so.

Answer (score 5):

## Battle Snake

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Introduction

The classic snake game where bots control the snakes. Can you create a bot that out lives the rest?

Snakes will enter the arena and hope to survive. Eat pellets and grow in length. Can you force your competition to crash and die while you survive?

See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQKWIM83Yd8) for visuals of my simple bot playing against itself. I am sure you can do better!

## Features

- Real-time graphics provided by [Love2D](https://love2d.org/)
- Multiple snakes per game
- Solo game as well
- Humans can play too!
- Highly configurable settings
- Supports any programming language that can use sockets.

## Requirements

- [Love2D](https://love2d.org/): 2D game engine written for Lua
- Socket-compatible programming language
- [Controller](https://github.com/dbaileychess/battlesnake): The main controller for this challenege

### Optional

- [Lua winapi](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi): Handy way to spawn processes in the background

## Controller Contents

1. `main.lua`: Main loop for Love.
2. `snake.lua`: Support library for game mechanics
3. `config.lua`: Configuration settings.
4. `bots\`: location of externally-defined bots

   1. `simple.lua`: Example bot written in Lua

## Executing

Run the love2d executable on the controller directory

`love.exe <location_of>\battlesnake`

or

[Recommended] Use [ZeroBrane Studio](https://studio.zerobrane.com/) with the 'Love' interpreter. Change your project directory to where you installed the controller, and then run the script in ZeroBrane. You'll still have to install Love separately.

## Configuration

All configurable options are located in the `config.lua` file in the controller. The options are detailed in that file itself.

## Rules

General snake rules apply. Hit something and you die. This includes the walls, other snakes, or even yourself.

Collisions happen before the board is updated. Therefore, if you move to a spot where another snake's tail is, it will still cause a collision. Even though it could be moving away that turn. If two or more snakes enter the same spot the same turn, they all collide with each other.

Eat a pellet and gain points. You also grow in size for a number of turns. Your head continues moving but your tail stays stationary until you stop growing.

## Mechanics

The game uses a server-client model, where the main game loop is the server and each snake is a client. The game communicates to each snake over TCP through an assigned port. The default host is the `localhost`, no external networks are required.

When the game starts, it will start each snake (aka bot) by starting its associated program and sending the IP ADDRESS and PORT and PLAYER ID to it as input arguments:

`bots\someBot.exe 127.0.0.1 52311 1`

The main server then waits for a socket connection from that bot at the given IP and PORT. If the connection times out, it will error and the game will not start. If the server receives a connection from the bot, it will proceed on to the next bot.

Once all bots are started and connected to the server, the game will be generated. Bots are expected to block until receiving data from the server. Typically this is just an infinite loop with a blocking `socket.receive()` call at the top of the loop.

### Board

The game board can be of any width and height. The coordinate system starts at `x = 1`, `y = 1` at the top-left. Increasing `x` values go left-to-right and increasing `y` values go top-to-bottom. The board has hard walls, hitting them will kill your snake. (Lua is 1-based, that is why it starts at 1)

### Order of Events

1. First the game settings are broadcast to all bots

   1. Board Information

      `bi width,height`

      Where `width` and `height` are integer values
   2. Pellet Location

      `p x,y`

      Where `x` and `y` are integer values `>= 1` and `<=` to their respective `width` and `height`.
   3. For each bot

      - For each body part, starting at the head and going to the tail

        `si snake_id x,y`

        Where `snake_id` is an integer value, and `x` and `y` are as described before.
   4. Ready signal

      `ready`

      All bots are initialized by now, so the next command will be from the main game loop.
2. Main Loop

   1. For each tick (tick is when all snake movements will be applied)

      1. Server will broadcast to each bot

         `mov`

         The bot needs to respond to this request with a direction to head in

         - `r` Head Right
         - `l` Head Left
         - `u` Head Up
         - `d` Head Down

         If the bot doesn't respond within a specified time, it will continue to move in its previous direction. (Previous direction is `r` on the first turn)

         The bot should send a single char back, nothing more will be parsed.
      2. Check End Game Conditions

         If the game ended this tick each bot will be sent either a `quit` or nil message from the server. Each bot is expected to clean up after itself when it receives this signal.
      3. Updated Pellet Info [optional]

         If a pellet was eaten this tick, a new pellet packet will be broadcast to all active bots

         `p x,y`
      4. Server broadcasts snake deltas that were applied this turn

         `s snake_id new_x,new_y,removed_x,removed_y`

         Where all parameters are integers. `new_x` and `new_y` are the new head location of a given snake.

         If `removed_x` and `removed_y` are `>= 1`, this is where the tail **used** to be, so each bot knows the updated board.

         If `remove_x` and `removed_y` are `== -1`, then that bot is actively growing in size, so its tail didn't move.

         If a snake died this tick, its deltas will not be broadcast. It is up to the bots to remove the body from their game state.

See the [example bot](https://github.com/dbaileychess/battlesnake/blob/master/bots/simple.lua) for details

## Matches

Games are grouped together in best-of matches. For the purposes of the bots, they do not need to understand the concept of a match. The bot that wins the required number of games in a match is declared the match winner.

## Scoring

1. Scoring

   - Match winner: +2500 points per match
   - Last Man Standing: +1000 points per game
   - Pellets Eaten: +50 points per pellet
   - Game Ticks Alive: +1 point per tick

   If two or more bots enter the same square on the same tick, they all die. If this square happened to be the pellet, none of those bots will be rewarded the pellet points. However, the pellet will be "consumed" and a new location will be generated for the remaining bots to eat.

   If there is a tie at the end of the game among the bots, the game is a wash. A new game will be started.
2. King-of-the-hill Scoring

   This challenge will combine two parts: A solo effort and a classic king-of-the-hill part.

   Each bot will be given the same random seed at the start of the competition. There will also be imposed a maximum time between eating pellets to prevent bots from going around in circles to farm points.

   1. Solo

      Each bot will enter into a 10-game match to see how long it lasts and how well it eats by itself. The scores of each game in the match will be summed to compose its final Solo-score.
   2. King-of-the-hill

      All the bots will enter into a best-of-39 match. If the game ends and there is still a final living bot, the game still end at that point. That bot will be given the last man standing bonus.

      The scores of each game will be summed and composed into the snakes final KOTH-score.
   3. Final Scoring

      All the bots will be ranked in each part separately. Ties in ranks are permitted at this stage. Then their positional rank in each part will be summed together to give their final score. The bot with the lowest combined rank wins!

      In case of a tie at this level, the bot with the better KOTH rank will win. If still a tie, the bot with the better Solo rank will win.

### Sandbox Questions

My biggest concerns

1. Requires a few third-party programs to work. So that will limit the number of people who enter.
2. Requires sockets. I couldn't figure out a good way with Lua\Love2d to have bidirectional pipes with `STDIN` and `STDOUT`. So I thought sockets would be the best alternative to open the challenge to as many people as possible.
3. Too hard?
4. Haven't optimized scoring yet.

Answer (score 5):

> This is a proposal adopted by programmer5000. Any feedback before I post it?

## Seven-segment usage

I have an old digital clock and I am concerned the individual segments of the digits might run out of magical binary energy or whatever powers them. To know which of the segments on the clock will fail first I want to know what is the percentage of time each segment is lit.

The challenge is to compute the percentage of time any segment on a digital clock is lit.

### Input

The input will be in the form **X.L**, where:

- X is a number from 1 to 4. 1 is the left-most number of the clock, 4 the right-most
- L is a letter from a to g or a number from 1 to 7
- the separator can be changed to fit your needs (no separator is an option)

[image: Disposition of segments, image source: Wikipedia]
[image: Disposition of segments plus numbers image source: Wikipedia]]

### Output

The output, is a percentage, given with at least 2 figures after the decimal point. It can be rounded or truncated to the closest value if you want to keep a limited number of digits.

Valid outputs: 0.74, 32.47, 7.5 (for 7.50)

### Additional stuff

The clock is in 24 hours format (so 22:45 is a valid time).

We consider the clock started working at 0:00 so the challenge is effectively working out what percentage of a complete day a single segment is lit.

The first number is not lit when it is 0.

Lit segments for each number:

- 1: b c
- 2: a b d e g
- 3: a b c d g
- 4: b c f g
- 5: a c d f g
- 6: a c d e f g
- 7: a b c
- 8: a b c d e f g
- 9: a b c d f g
- 0: a b c d e f

### Examples

- 1.b => 58.33
- 3.e => 33.33
- 2.d => 70.83
- 4.d => 70.00

Full list of outputs [here](http://pastebin.com/ZLSFNSug)

### Winner

Code golf, most probably, though I am not sure yet this is the best format (I am not too interested in the input parsing and the output formatting, they might be an obstacle to golfing?)

Comment: AIUI there are 28 valid inputs, so you could provide a full list of test cases as a pastebin. I would remove "*No hard coding of results*": if hard-coding the 28 cases is shorter than the calculation, then IMO that's a flaw which makes the question not worth bothering with at all rather than something which can be worked around; and the issue of whether or not an answer "hard-codes the results" is likely to be grey rather than black or white.

Comment: List of results added, I'll need to double check them. Hard coding removed, yes I don't see how "cheating" would be an issue. Any hard-coding would have to be quite constructive to be efficient.

Comment: I am removing limitations on the output as well, I don't think it brings anything to the challenge.
I have started to golf a solution in python, I think there are a few interesting possibilities to optimise the use of strings describing segments used for each digit.

Comment: Can I post this abandoned proposal?

Comment: @programmer5000 certainly, just try to make it better :)

Answer (score 5):

## Tron Game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Write a Tron bot!

The aim of the game is to make as many moves on a grid as possible without moving onto a space that has already been occupied in the current game. If your bot is unable to make such a move, it loses the round. The board does not wrap so bots can not go off the side of the arena.

### Game IO:

Your bot will be written in python and will create a class that inherits from `BotSkeleton`. An example test bot is shown below.

```
from bot_skeleton import BotSkeleton
from typing_hints import PositionDict, Position
from board import Board
from typing import List

import random


class Test(BotSkeleton):
    def make_move(self, board: Board, positions: PositionDict) -> Position:
        self.board = board
        self.position = positions[self.bot_id]
        valid_moves = self.get_valid_moves()
        try:
            return random.choice(valid_moves)
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def get_valid_moves(self) -> List[Position]:
        moves = filter(self.board.position_valid, ((self.position[0]+1, self.position[1]),
                                                   (self.position[0]-1, self.position[1]),
                                                   (self.position[0], self.position[1]+1),
                                                   (self.position[0], self.position[1]-1)))
        return list(moves)
```

(Type hints are not required but illustrated here  to help understanding)

- `position` is a 2-long tuple containing 2 integers.
- `positions` is a `Dict[bot_id, position]`
- `board` can be indexed with a `position`.

  - `get_random_empty_pos() -> position` - returns a empty position at random in the board
  - `position_valid(position) -> bool` - returns if this move is valid (but not next to the position given)
  - `copy() -> List[List[int]` - returns a 2d list that can be modifiable of the current board state
  - `EMPTY` - the id for an empty space
- The value you return must be a `position`, and must also have a distance of 1 from this, not including diagonals.

Built in attributes for `BotSkeleton`:

- `log` - contains a file object that you may write to
- `no_bots` - the number of bots the game began with
- `bot_id` - you're bot's id number.

Methods in `Board`:

- `get_random_empty_pos() -> Position` - Returns a position at random that is empty
- `position_valid(pos: Position) -> bool` - returns if a position is inside the board and is currently empty
- `copy() -> Board` - return a copy of the board that is writable

### Tournament structure

- Every bot will get pitted against every other bot in a giant arena

  - That is to say every single bot will be in every battle
  - The size of the arena will be `(30, 30)`. This may be increased depending on number of bots entered.

#### General rules that I can't find better places for

- Your bot may NOT use any file storage except for write-only access to the log file provided
- Your bot must be written in Python 3. Sorry java people
- You may enter as many bots as you want
- Your bot must not attempt to subvert the game state

#### I reserve the right to disqualify any bot from the competition

(but shall only do so after telling you I will do so and you not making any changes required)

#### You may download the controller [here](https://github.com/muddyfish/TronKOTH)

### Results:

- Results here

### Sandbox notes:

- Should there be a minimum starting distance between players?

Comment: What happens if two bots go on the same position at the same time?

Comment: Is the goal really to survive as many moves as possible, and not to survive longer than the other guy?

Comment: probably change "sorry" to "sorry not sorry"

Answer (score 5):

## Interpret a Formal Grammar

Given a context-free grammar, and a string, parse the string using the formal grammar and output the matches for the non-terminals.

### Examples

First line is string, following lines are grammar, then is the main grammar to parse, last line is output.

```
123

n -> any of
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
N -> n N
     n

N

N [ n [1], n [2], n [3] ]
```

```
2+2*(4/2)

o -> any of
     + - / *
n -> any of
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
E -> o E E'
     ( E ) E'
     n E'
E' -> o E E'
     o E'
     ε

E

E [ n [2], E' [ o [+], E [ n [2], E' [ε]  ] ] ]
```

```
a b

S -> S' S
     ε
S' -> a   b

S

S [ S' [a], S' [ ], S' [b] ]
```

This grammar is the same as regex: `[a b]+`

### Spec

Details:

- All recursion will be right-recursive
- Rule names will consist of `A-Z a-z α β γ Γ` and may have a `'` at the end.

  - Valid Rule names:

    - `A`
    - `Γ`
    - `AB`
    - `αβ`
    - `foo'`
    - `faαβdg'`
  - Invalid Rule names:

    - `'ab` (`'` will be at the end)
    - `ab''` (two `''`s)
    - `code golf` (spaces not allowed in rule names)
- Nonterminals will be lowercase, terminals upercase
- A derivation format will be:

  ```
  <rule name> -> <rule>
                 <rule>
                 <rule, etc.>
  ```

  meaning the rules will be lined up (when in a monospace font), by spaces.
- Symbols/rule-names will never be repeated
- `ε` (epsilon) means empty. i.e. `""`

### Rule definition:

- If the initial rule is "any of", the second rule will exist and will be a space separated list of symbols/rule-names (maybe more than one char). There will be no rules after this
- Else, the rule will consist of space-seperated tokens which either refer to a rule or a literal. If it is not a valid rule name, assume it is a literal which should be treated as if it is a terminal.

Summing up, for input you will be given the string to parse, the grammar, and the rule to parse.

#### Output:

You may output in whichever format you like as long as it is able to convey the following information. You must somehow label the match to their respective rule names. You may optionally not label terminals.

### Challenge Rules:

- Feel free to assume the input can always be parsed by the given grammar.
- External libraries (ones that have to be imported), are not allowed
- If your language has built-in parsing tools (e.g. regex) those are allowed
- If your language has a built-in to parse a grammar (i.e. some formal grammar parser), these are allowed but your solution is non-competing and you must clearly state this in the **header** of your answer.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins!

I may award a bounty to any particularly ingenious solutions, so try to add an explanation!

Comment: 1. Why the special-case Greek letters in the valid rule names? That seems to add complication for no benefit. 2. Am I correct in thinking that the only way to match a literal space character is as part of an "any of" rule? Some test cases involving literal spaces would be useful. 3. What does "*Symbols will never be repeated*" mean? 4. The spec for the rule definition uses the words "symbols" and "tokens". It's not clear to me whether these are synonyms, and if not then what the distinction is. 5. May we assume that there is a valid parse tree for the given input?

Comment: @PeterTaylor greek letters are often used in grammars. I'll address number 2, and 4.  Symbols are a name of a derivation(s).

Comment: Trying to outsource compiler design for cheddar? Lol, jk, +1!

Comment: I must say that I never saw any Greek letters except for episilon in the formal language and parsing courses I took, but that wasn't really my point. My point was the special-casing of three lower-case and one upper-case Greek letters. If rule names could contain any character other than `- >` then it would be simpler. If they could contain any Unicode alphabetic character then it would be simpler (at least for regex users). Also, 6. "*Nonterminals will be lowercase, terminals upercase*" Does this mean that mixed case tokens are always literals?

Answer (score 5):

### Count the Cats [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

This is a cat:

[image]

Specifically, that is my cat. She is my only cat. And, in that image, there is only one cat: her.

These are also cats ([image credit](https://www.flickr.com/photos/suetupling/2800697500)):

[image]

In that picture, there are two cats. It is relatively easy to count them, thanks to their distinct coloring.

This is a picture of 5 cats ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Laitche-P013.jpg)):

[image]

It's harder to differentiate the cats because of their similar coloring, but there are definitely 5.

This is a landscape ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cumulus_Clouds_over_Yellow_Prairie2.jpg)):

[image]

There are no cats in this image.

### The Challenge

Given an image, output the number of cats in the image.

### Rules

- Submissions must output and terminate within 1 minute for a single image.
- Any common image format is acceptable for input, as long as no additional data (such as the number of cats present in the image) is encoded in the format.
- Submissions must be fully deterministic, and make a genuine attempt at counting the cats. Outputting a random number or a consistent but unrelated number (such as the value of the last hex digit of the SHA-256 hash of the image data) is not allowed.
- The images in the test cases will contain no animals besides cats. There may or may not be humans in the images - they are not cats, and thus should not be counted as cats.

### Scoring

The score for a single image is the square of the difference between the true number of cats in the image and the output of the submission (`(actual - output)**2`). The total score is the sum of all of the individual scores. The submission with the *lowest* score wins.

[scoring images TBD]

Comment: I feel like this is probably a dupe of either the [goat question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71631/31625) or the [rice question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40831/31625). I'm not sure that it being a test battery question or the precise subimage to identify really makes it much different from these other ones?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't think it's a dupe of goats - goats wanted a boolean classification, where this one asks for a count. The rice question is closer, but there is a possibility (and perhaps a need) for different approaches, given that a) cats can overlap, b) cats come in different colors, and c) cats have much more complex shapes than rice grains (which are ellipses).

Comment: "Submissions must output and terminate within 10 seconds for a single image." I don't know about that, counting the amount of _cats_ and only cats is a rather difficult task already, a 10-second limit seems really small. Perhaps a couple minutes?

Comment: Also, I think there should be some specification for how the cats would appear. At least having the full cat's face showing would make this challenge more approachable. If a test-case shows the [back of a cat](http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/25193-Tabby-kitten-back-view-white-background.jpg) that seems a bit too difficult for a PPCG challenge. Also: Will there be a mix of cats and other animals? Are built-ins allowed (I'm very sure there's mathematica builtin)?

Comment: @Upgoat The time requirement can be extended. The number of cats will always be clear to a human viewer with 20/20 eyesight and adequate attention for detail. The challenge is about counting cats, not about picking out camouflaged cats, so there won't be any excessive trickery in the test images. Built-ins are allowed, but I'm on the fence about whether or not I'm going to allow them to be competitive, since Mathematica is likely the only language that would benefit from built-ins.

Comment: Showing a picture of a dog and expecting a zero output doesn't seem fair. Writing a program that distinguishes between dogs and cats seems like a difficult enough task as it is, and you have it here as sort of an afterthought. Empty images should be emptier, imo.

Comment: @Liam On the other hand, if all of the test images consisted of 0-5 cats and no other animals, it would be too easy to get a perfect score. Having harder test cases means that submissions will have room for improvement, and thus there will be more competition.

Comment: Is fitting allowed? I think learning will probably be the most practical approach to this challenge. Though this does need some specification before it's ready to post imo and limits on the possible inputs as I doubt any answer will be able to conform to the wide variety of things cats can be e.g. color, position, shape, size, direction, camera position, etc.

Comment: @Downgoat As per usual with these types of challenges, optimizing for the test cases is not allowed. However, given that a ML-oriented approach would be interesting and perform well on this challenge, I'd be willing to include a training set, separate from the scoring set. As for limits on possible inputs, I'm trying to work out a good set.

Comment: I think the part about the dog makes this a [chameleon challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260) -- distinguishing a cat from a dog is much harder than identifying and counting cats on an image free of distracters.

Comment: @xnor On the other hand, without the distracters, it would likely be too easy to get a perfect score.

Comment: Distinguishing a cat from a dog on a picture already requires decently advanced algorithms (CNNs are the first that come to mind) which in turn require a LOT of training data to generalize decently.

Comment: @Fatalize Would using non-mammilian animals (such as lizards and birds) be better in your opinion?

Comment: @Mego It probably would be easier because it wouldn't force people to use machine learning techniques (You could use texture comparison to distinguish feathers from scales, color detection, etc.). Counting the number of each is an added difficulty that makes it maybe too difficult as a whole. Only classifying is easier but probably a dupe of the goats challenge. Only counting might be good though.

Comment: The problem with this scoring technique is that even if people make legit attempts at counting the cats, they will try to optimize their code for the limited test set, which will make their approaches less general on new data. One solution could be to provide a validation set (for say 2 weeks if that's the time frame in which you can post an answer) on which people can evaluate their answers, and choose the winning answer based on a test set that was not available during those 2 weeks containing new images.

Answer (score 5):

## The Ifelse Tower

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

You are an inhabitant of the whimsical country of *Forance*, filled with programmers.

Life in *Forance* is said to be extremely repetitive, which isn't good to attract tourists. For this, authorities of *Forance* want to hire someone to
print tons of postcards to promote their most iconic landmark: ***the Ifelse tower***.

```
                   if
                   if
                   if
                   if
                   if
                   if
                   if
                  else
                  else
                 ifelse
                  else
                  else
                ifelseif
                ifelseif
               elseifelse
              ifelseifelse
            elseifelseifelse
              ifelseifelse
              ifelseifelse
              else    else
             else      else
            else        else
           else          else
          else            else
       ifelseifelseifelseifelseif
       ifelseifelseifelseifelseif
       ifelseifelseifelseifelseif
       ifelseifelseifelseifelseif
      elseifelseif    elseifelseif
     elseifelse          elseifelse
    ifelseif                ifelseif
   ifelse                      ifelse
  ifelse                        ifelse
 ifelse                          ifelse
ifelse                            ifelse
```

But, of course, they want to do this with the least possible cost. So, if you want this job, you have to show you can do this with very little code

### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes no input, and outputs to STDOUT the Ifelse tower.

### Rules

- Leading and traling new lines are not allowed
- Leading spaces are (of course) a must
- All lines must be **at most** the same lenght as the base (40 chars). This means you are free to use or not trailing spaces on each line, as long as they don't surpass the base's lenght
- Standard loopholes are not allowed

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes gets the job -err wins

Comment: I'd allow a single optional trailing linefeed. A lot of languages print full lines by default. In some it's annoying to suppress that and in some it's impossible.

Comment: Why enforced an output to stdout?

Comment: This challenge proposal has been inactive for over a month. I would like to take ownership of the challenge and make it ready for posting. Please let me know within the next 14 days if you have any objections and would still like to finish and post this challenge yourself.

Answer (score 5):

## Esolang Interpreters

Using a programming language from [this](http://pastebin.com/96E0f209) version of [this](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Turing_complete) list, write an interpreter for the next language on the list. For example, if you choose to start with LOCK, you would write an interpreter for LOLCODE. Continue this pattern (use LOLCODE to write an LCBF iterpreter, etc)
If specs of a language are unclear and the compiler is nonexistant or closed-source, ask me and I'll decide whether or not to take it off the list.

Wining Criteria:
The longest streak of compilers wins.

---

Proposed Edits:
Make several defined starting points.  (this would make many answers too similar, though)

---

Edits:
changed from list of all esolangs to just turing complete ones.

Comment: I like it, but it may be a trivial task depending on what language you choose

Comment: I think this would be better as a similar challenge to the enterprise quality code, but where the winner is the one who does the most languages at the end at you need to go in order. If you don't think so, I'll make a separate sandbox post.

Comment: In order to prevent edits, you can simply use the version in the url: https://esolangs.org/w/index.php?title=Language_list&oldid=49177

Comment: I agree with Easterly, but I'd also make it a cycle based-system.  Aka, the interpreter for "!!!Batch" must be written before the interpreter for "???" can be written.  You could also have multiple starting points, one for each letter.

Comment: Actually, better idea, score them based on the number of *consecutive* interpreters they write.

Comment: How will you deal with cases where one language is a joke language and/or not Turing complete, and therefore cannot interpret the next language?

Comment: @El'endiaStarman should I use [this](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Turing_complete) list instead?

Comment: @Nathan Merrill I think I will do that, yes. Great suggestions.

Comment: @BaldBantha: That would be better, but you may still run into problems such as languages being *technically* Turing complete, but entirely impractical. For instance, try multiplying two numbers in [Pancake Stack](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pancake_Stack).

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Oh, well this challenge isn't supposed to be easy. I assume the first few answers will include 2-3 interpreters (depends on the starting points, TBH), but I think it would stall for a while. TLDR: I don't feel like classifying several hundred langueges as practical or not.

Comment: The bigger issue I see is that many languages don't have completely solid specs, so it's not clear what counts as a valid interpreter of the language.

Answer (score 5):

## Slay

This KoTH is based off of the computer game, [Slay](http://www.windowsgames.co.uk/slay.html).  Try it out, its way fun.

## TLDR

- You start off with a bunch of small territories: you try to merge them and capture as much land as possible.
- **Each territory has its own economy:** each hex gives you 1 gold per turn.
- Warriors can capture and protect territory, but cost money to maintain.
- If you run out of money, all units on that territory die

## Map

- A hexagonal map is generated using Perlin noise.
- Each hexagon is randomly assigned to a player.  Players will start with a similar number of hexagons, as well as a similar number of territories (see below)
- Hexagons that touch the edge of the map (or a hole in the middle), are on the beach
- Each tile has a 1/5 chance of starting with a tree: Palm tree if on the beach, pine tree otherwise
- Hexagons may contain a warrior, house, tower, grave, or palm/pine tree

## Territory

- A block of 2 or more hexagons with the same owner is considered a territory
- All territories contain exactly 1 house.

  - If a territory ever doesn't have a house, it gets one in a random location, preferring: empty hexes, trees, graves, towers, and then warriors. (in that order)
- A territory "death" occurs when it is reduced/split into a single hexagon.

  - Houses turn into a pine/palm (if on the beach) tree
  - Warriors die (turn into graves) at the start of their next turn
  - Towers disappear
- If two territories grow so that they touch, they merge and the smaller territory's house disappears.

#### Finanaces

- Each territory has its own reserve/income
- Each territory starts with 10 gold in its reserve
- Territories generate 1 income at the end of each turn for each tree-less hexagon
- If you don't have enough money to pay for your units at the end of your turn, then *all* of your units in that territory will die (turn into graves) at the start of your next turn.
- If a territory splits, then the larger of the two gets *all* of the reserve.
- If a territory combines, their reserves combine

#### Defense

- Certain objects give defense to its hexagon and all adjacent friendly hexagons:

  - Houses (1): cannot be built, but every territory has exactly one
  - Towers (2): can be built for 15 gold
  - Warriors (strength): see below

## Map objects

#### Warriors

- A warrior has a strength between 1 to 4 (inclusive)
- A warrior costs `10*strength` to build
- **A warrior costs `2*3^(strength-1)` gold each turn.**  This means that a 4-str warrior costs you a whopping 54 gold per turn
- A warrior can move a maximum of 4 hexes each turn.  Moving through enemy lands is not allowed.  Capturing enemy lands ends the warrior's turn.
- If you move/build a warrior onto a friendly warrior, they combine, and their strength is summed.

  - Trying to make a warrior of `strength > 4` doesn't work
  - If the friendly warrior hadn't moved yet, the new unit can still move
- A warrior can capture an adjacent hexagon if its defense rating is **lower** than its strength

#### Trees

- Trees prevent a hexagon from generating income
- Trees grow at the end of each round:

  - Palm trees grow onto all unoccupied adjacent beach tiles
  - Any unoccupied tile that is adjacent to two pine trees grows another pine
- Trees can be removed by moving a unit onto them
- Graves turn into a pine/palm (if on beach) tree at the end of the round

## Game flow

- Between 2 to 6 players can play on a single map.  (The size of the map depends on the number of players.  You can expect about 50 hexagons per player)
- Turn order is randomized, but is consistent within a single game
- Once a player owns all hexagons, they win!

Comment: @zyabin101 still not ready yet.

Comment: @zyabin101 + others finished my post!  It took me a bit to ensure I got all corner cases correct.

Answer (score 5):

## Sesquiprimes

Given a non-negative integer `N`, output the `N`th sesquiprime integer.

We say that a positive integer `I` is sesquiprime if `I + ⌊I/2⌋` is prime (where  `⌊...⌋` is the floor function).

For example, `25` is a sesquiprime because `25 + ⌊25/2⌋ = 25 + 12 = 37`, which is prime.

[Sequence A158708](https://oeis.org/A158708) is the sequence of prime sesquiprimes.

#### Inputs and outputs

- `N` may be 0-indexed or 1-indexed, please indicate which of the two your solution uses.
- Inputs and outputs must be in the decimal base.
- `N` may be taken through `STDIN`, as a function argument, or anything similar.
- The output may be printed to `STDOUT`, returned from a function, or anything similar.

#### Test cases

The following test cases are 0-indexed.

```
N        Output

0        2
1        5
2        9
4        21
8        45
15       93
16       101
23       149
42       305
100      853
1000     11693
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I don't think the link to prime sesquiprimes adds anything other than a possibility for mistakes by people too lazy to read specs fully (like me)

Comment: @JonathanAllan True. Would adding it as a comment be better to make it less appear like part of the challenge?

Comment: Including the link as a comment and/or prefixed by **Related:** would probably be clearer.

Comment: This seems close to finding primes that are 1 mod 3.

Answer (score 5):

## Flexagonal datastructures

Being programmers, watching us flex aren't very interesting. Today we change that! In this challenge you will lex and flex hexaflexagons.

## About

For a video introduction, watch [viharts video(s) on flexagons](https://youtu.be/VIVIegSt81k)

A flexagon is a shape that you can flex to reveal faces other than the top and bottom one; we are making a hexahexaflexagon, which has 6 faces. See the image below on how to fold a hexahexaflexagon out of a strip of paper.

[image: hexahexaflexagon construction]

`A` shows both sides of the strip. The two white triangles are glued together.
This is how you would flex it:

[image: flexing the flexagon]

Below is a diagram of possible states and their relationships:

[image: Diagram v6]

The colored circles represent the 6 triangles with the same number from the first image. Each of the circes have two colors- the bottom most represent the back face (what you would see if you where to flip your flexagon around), which you don't have to consider in this challenge.

The gray circles represent how you can flex your flexagon in any given state: there are 4 different ways to flex it, we call these `Left`, `Right`, `Up` and `Down`. You don't actually flex in these directions, the important bit is that some are opposite to each other.

If you are in the center you can use `Left` and `Right` to go to the other center ones. To get out of the center you use `Up` and `Down`. If you aren't in the center you cannot use `Left` or `Right`.

```
Left/Down = clockwise
Right/Up  = anti-clockwise
```

## Challenge

Create a function or program that take as input what should be on the 18 front faces and the 18 back faces of a flexagon, a sequence of left, right, up and down flexes, and return the 8 visible faces after the flexes.

Example computation:

```
flex "hexaflexaperplexia" 
     "flexagationdevices" 
     [Right, Right, Left]

Divide a strip of paper into 19 triangles:
1/2\3/1\2/3\1/2\3/1\2/3\1/2\3/1\2/3   Front
4/4\5/5\6/6\4/4\5/5\6/6\4/4\5/5\6/6   Back

Write "hexaflexaperplexia" to the front of the paper strip:
1/2\3/1\2/3\1/2\3/1\2/3\1/2\3/1\2/3

hexaflexaperplexia
123123123123123123
h  a  e  p  p  x     Face 1, Initially the front face
 e  f  x  e  l  i    Face 2, Initially the back face
  x  l  a  r  e  a   Face 3, Initially hidden


Write "flexagationdevices" to the back of the paperstrip:
4/4\5/5\6/6\4/4\5/5\6/6\4/4\5/5\6/6

flexagationdevices
445566445566445566
fl    at    ev       Face 4, up from 3
  ex    io    ic     Face 5, up from 2
    ag    nd    es   Face 6, up from 1


Flex it [Right, Right, Left]
  The initial visible face is 1: "haeppx"
  flexing Right ..
  The current visible face is 2: "efxeli"
  flexing Right ..
  The current visible face is 3: "xlarea"
  flexing Left ..
  The current visible face is 2: "efxeli"
  flexed [Right, Right, Left]!

outputting "efxeli"
```

Example input and expected output:

```
> hexaflexaperplexia flexagationdevices RRL
= efxeli

> loremipsumdolorsit hexaflexamexicania LUU
= riuort

> abcdefghijklmnopqr stuvwxyz1234567890 UL
= I can't flex that way :(

> abcdefghijklmnopqr stuvwxyz1234567890 RRRRLLUDDUUUULDD
= uv1278
```

## Rules

- You may take input and return output in any reasonable way
- If the input is impossible, you should indicate so in some way that is distinct from regular output
- Standard loopholes apply
- This is `Codegolf`. Shortest code in bytes win.

Comment: The diagram is at best confusing. The overlapping arrows are hard to read, and the fact that they're directional is just plain wrong. Then the example computation is very cryptic. To be useful the examples need to explain what each line of text means, and they should avoid duplicating letters. It would be good to make the first example show the output with zero flexes. I made my first hexaflexagon at least 25 years ago, and I carried one in my wallet for years to play with when bored, so if I find this spec lacking imagine how it must look to people who don't know anything about them!

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is this remotely better?

Answer (score 5):

## Draw me a Brick Wall!

I'm drawing up a plan for my house extension - and I need a simple graphic for walls...

## The Challenge

Your task is to create a program, which takes an input of the wall's dimensions and draws a brick wall, in the style of the one below.

```
[__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][_
```

Please notice that the rows alternate between beginning on a full brick (`[__]`) and a half brick (`_]`), to create a more realistic, stable wall.

The input will be two integers, separated by a single comma, such as `4,3` or `2,6`. You can assume both integers are positive and larger than 0.

The first integer specifies the width (in bricks) and the second specifies the height (in rows of bricks).

## Rules / Notes

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (in bytes) wins. However, don't feel like you have to beat everyone else to post your solution - I'd love to see your code!
- Standard loopholes apply, no reading from external files.
- You may optionally take the input with brackets/braces, for example `(4,3)` or `[4,3]` as long as you specify this in your answer.
- You should take the input from STDIN and output on STDOUT - if your language does not have these, please use the nearest equivalent.

### Test Cases

Input: `1,1`

```
[__]
```

Input: `2,4`

```
[__][__]
_][__][_
[__][__]
_][__][_
```

Input: `5,10`

```
[__][__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][__][_
[__][__][__][__][__]
_][__][__][__][__][_
```

## Example: Python 3, 65 bytes

This is somewhat golfed but still readable.

```
w,h=eval(input())
for i in range(h):print(('[__]','_][_')[i%2]*w)
```

Comment: [very closely related or dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49536/47066)

Comment: [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90022/all-in-all-its-just-uh-another-trick-in-code-golf) is related too I think

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This seems like a great first challenge. There are a few related challenges regarding brick walls, like [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49536/build-a-steady-brick-wall) (inputs as different sized bricks) or [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/is-the-brick-structure-stable) (is it stable). But, I think this challenge is different enough. Instead of having different sized bricks as input, this simply asks for two inputs for an NxM wall, which is imho different enough from the first challenge.

Comment: @Emigna I'd like to think they're different, as this one is a 'more static' string to print and doesn't require an algorithm to work out a stable wall first - however I understand that they are closely related.

Comment: @Dada Hmm, that one might be more related than the two related ones linked by me, and more towards a dupe (despite the different ASCII used for the bricks themselves). But we'll perhaps wait on some more feedback from other users.

Comment: The one Dada linked is similar, but not quite a dupe. The brick structure is quite a bit more flexible in Luis' challenge, given that the input is total character width and height plus a horizontal offset, whereas here it's in number of bricks.

Comment: I'd still call the previous brick printing one a dupe. The offsetting pattern is the same, and in most of the answers it would be easy to replace constants with inputs.

Answer (score 5):

## A Game of Knights

In this King of the Hill, you control 10 Knights.  You need to surround your enemy before they surround you.

Each Knight has 3 possible actions:

- Dash: Move 3 squares in a cardinal direction.  If there is a knight in your path, move as far as you can.
- Leap: Move 2 squares in a cardinal direction.  If there is a knight on your destination square, don't move at all.
- Push: Move 1 square in a cardinal direction.  If there is a knight on your destination square, and no knight or wall behind him, you both move 1 square.

Each round will have a **Planning Phase** and then an **Action Phase**.

**Planning:**

During the planning phase, players will alternate creating a plan until both players have created 10 plans.

- **A plan consists of either an action type or a cardinal direction** (not both).
- A plan also includes the knight that will perform the action
- All plans are revealed to both players

**Action:**

- Actions occur in the same order that they were planned.
- If you planned an action type, you will be able to choose the direction.  If you planned a cardinal direction, you will be able to chose the action type you want.

After the action phase, if any knights are on the same location they started at (at the start of the round) are captured and removed from the game.  You win by capturing all other knights.

Other info:

- Cardinal means North, East, South, or West
- The board is a 10x10 board.  Your knights start as a line at the bottom of the board.
- Walls block movement and cannot be pushed.
- You don't have to plan an action for every knight, and a knight can take multiple actions.
- There are a maximum of 1000 rounds.  After those 1000 rounds, the winner is the player with the most knights.  (A tie is allowed).
- The starting player for a game is randomized, and that player starts every round.

You have won the game when you opponent cannot make any mobility actions.

Comment: Man, now I want to play this in person.

Comment: Isn't it possible to form your knights into a solid 2×5 rectangle (thus immune to pushing), away from the starting squares, before the enemy can move and push it? That would guarantee you couldn't lose. Also you should clarify whether you can plan two actions for the same knight, and if you can, whether it gets to take both or only one.

Comment: @ais523 movement is not simultaneous. You start as a  1x10 line.  A knight could take 10 moves on a round

Comment: To be clear, as long as you have 10 knights, you need to move each of them every round or lose the ones you didn't move, assuming you don't push. Correct?

Comment: Does the same player go first in each round, or does that alternate?

Comment: @isaacg correct.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've debated about this, and I think the same player will go  first in each round.  The player that goes first will be randomized each game, but it will be consistent round to round.  Otherwise, you end up with a player being able to move twice in a row.

Answer (score 5):

## Make A Rotating Emoji Globe

Your task is to make a globe out of the following characters, with the line being cleared ever 1/3 of a second:

You must clear the line your emoji globe on it and print the next one every approximate 1/3 of a second.
Output may be to the terminal or elsewhere.
The program must also continue until interrupted on purpose.
Also, your code may not contain the emoji globes themselves, but it may contain Unicode escapes.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard loopholes & rules apply.
May the best coder win...

Comment: Simple, fairly identical to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105323/blinking-twelve/105626#105626) in that you simply display a cycle of things, Most answers from that will fairly easily work copied over.

Comment: @ATaco How could I make it more challenging?

Comment: @ATaco I think it's sufficiently distinct--it requires clearing the line (an option in the other challenge), display unicode characters, and only displaying one character at a time.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I still feel I could distinguish my challenge a bit more, though...

Comment: Define clear the line? Does it have to clear the _line_, or does the whole terminal suffice?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Clearing the screen can be done in any way, as long as the globe appears to rotate onscreen.

Comment: It's even more similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101289/loading-forever. Printing a single character that cycles

Comment: @12Me21 How can I make it different, then?

Comment: Maybe you could require them to draw an actual rotating globe, given a map image. (It's a lot more complicated though)

Comment: @12Me21 I just had the idea to add a moon rotating around the earth. Help me think of how to implement it.

Comment: You could make it use the different moon phase emoji to display the proper phases or something

Comment: @12Me21, an actual rotating globe is potentially a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24326/194 - certainly some of the answers could be copied across.

Comment: Take as input the "spin speed" (ms delay), althought that's fairly trivial to handle.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I will do that.

Answer (score 5):

## Part I: [Triangular Manhattan Distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115217/8478)

## Part II: Triangular Chebyshev Distance

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[hexagonal-grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

The [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) on a regular grid is the number of orthogonal or diagonal steps one needs to take to reach one cell from another. That is, we can move either through the edge of a cell, or through a corner, to a neighbouring cell.

We can define a similar distance on other grids, for example the triangular grid. We can address the individual cells in the grid with the following indexing scheme, where each cell contains an `x,y` pair:

```
    ____________________________________...
   /\      /\      /\      /\      /\
  /  \ 1,0/  \ 3,0/  \ 5,0/  \ 7,0/  \
 / 0,0\  / 2,0\  / 4,0\  / 6,0\  / 8,0\
/______\/______\/______\/______\/______\...
\      /\      /\      /\      /\      /
 \ 0,1/  \ 2,1/  \ 4,1/  \ 6,1/  \ 8,1/
  \  / 1,1\  / 3,1\  / 5,1\  / 7,1\  /
   \/______\/______\/______\/______\/___...
   /\      /\      /\      /\      /\
  /  \ 1,2/  \ 3,2/  \ 5,2/  \ 7,2/  \
 / 0,2\  / 2,2\  / 4,2\  / 6,2\  / 8,2\  
/______\/______\/______\/______\/______\...
\      /\      /\      /\      /\      /
 \ 0,3/  \ 2,3/  \ 4,3/  \ 6,3/  \ 8,3/
  \  / 1,3\  / 3,3\  / 5,3\  / 7,3\  /
   \/______\/______\/______\/______\/___...
   /\      /\      /\      /\      /\
  .  .    .  .    .  .    .  .    .  .
 .    .  .    .  .    .  .    .  .    .
```

Now the Chebyshev distance on this grid is again the minimal number of steps across edges or corners to get from one cell to another. So you can move from `3,1` to any of its 12 neighbours:

2,1    4,1    3,2    (through edges)

3,0    1,2    5,2    (the opposite triangle through corners)

2,0    4,0    1,1
5,1    2,2    4,2    (the other triangles through corners)

For instance, the distance from `2,1` to `7,2` is `3`. The shortest path is generally not unique, but one way to make the distance in 3 steps is:

```
2,1 --> 4,1 --> 5,1 --> 7,2
```

### The Challenge

Given two coordinate pairs `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` from the above addressing scheme, return the Chebyshev distance between them.

You may assume that all four inputs are non-negative integers, each less than 128. You may take them in any order and arbitrarily grouped (four separate arguments, a list of four integers, two pairs of integers, a 2x2 matrix, ...).

You may write a [program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the [standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.

You may use any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/) are forbidden by default.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer – measured in *bytes* – wins.

### Test Cases

Each test case is given as `x1,y1 x2,y2 => result`.

```
1,2 1,2 => 0
0,1 1,1 => 1
1,0 1,1 => 1
2,1 7,2 => 3
```

*Will add more test cases when I have a reference implementation.*

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, thank you. With the slow response to the Manhattan variant, I do wonder whether this one will be a bit too tricky, but we'll see. :)

Comment: "_I do wonder whether this one will be a bit too tricky, but we'll see. :)_" I've found a solution for this one, but not for the other one yet. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh, would you mind sharing it? :)

Comment: I always make my answers in Java 7 btw, so I'll still be beaten by golfing answers. But this is what I came up with (I've also added an explanation of how I came up with the solution in the TIO footer): [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/k68ytvg)

Comment: Hmm, I just took another look at your part 1 challenge and realized my solution above for part 2 is incorrect.. :( Based on your current test cases I falsely assumed `x1,y1` is always smaller than `x2,y2`. So my code fails for a test case like `4,1 1,3`. Back to the drawing board.. Also, as to why I think this challenge is easier than part 1: In part 1 you had to determine whether the triangle was facing upwards (available: left; right; below) or facing downwards (available: left; right; above). With this challenge all 12 surrounding triangles - regardless of orientation - are accessible.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen but the exact coordinates/orientations of those 12 neighbours also change, right?

Comment: Yeah, was about to edit my comment again when I realized that.. If you have more test cases I'll take another look at this part 2. I'll start with part 1 for now. (PS: Have a nice weekend - apparently I can use it.. >.>)

Comment: Me again, more than one year later. I've currently set a bounty for your Part 1 challenge to give it more attention, which you may or may not have noticed based on the new answers given. If you have time, could you add more test cases for this one?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm not sure how soon I'll get around to that, because I'd want to write a reference implementation for that. If you want it post it soon, feel free to add them yourself (and optionally post the challenge yourself if you like).

Comment: Oh no, I'll patiently wait. I'm going on vacation soon anyway, so I won't have time to answer during that time. I just made that comment above as a reminder so it can hopefully be posted in the not to distant future. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [The Chroma Key to Success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132719/the-chroma-key-to-success?s=1|2.8930)

Comment: So essentially, for every pixel in the second image, if it's `#00FF00`, replace it with the corresponding pixel in the first image; otherwise, don't modify that pixel?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes.

Comment: I don't know image formats very well, but are we guaranteed that the image will be in 3-byte-RGB format? As in, is there transparency?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Assume the image is full opacity.

Comment: Please delete this, now that it is posted.

Answer (score 5):

## PPCG VS CR KotH

## I am working as fast as I can to get this ready. Please be patient. I have a real job and will attempt to work on this on vacation to the northern states using mobile. I give no promises.

I challenged CR to a KotH challenge. So here is the specs.

Two sides in a arena. 1000x1000. Resources scattered about. A giant area in the center filled with resources. You must build a base and defend your ancient.

You have a few kinds of buildings:

1. Wall: a simple wall that must be broken before walking through. It has `1/2/4/8` health (upgrades). It can be changed into a gate.
2. Gate: a gate that lets the side that made it walk through. Health: `1/2/2/4`
3. Turret: Deals `1/1/2/4` damage to the lowest health enemy within a `1/2/4/4` block radius and has `1/1/4/8` health.
4. Resource drop: a place that you can drop resources.  Has `2/2/4/6` health.
5. Tower of vision. Gives 10 sight radius with health of five. Costs two resources to build.

Upgrades are `1/2/3/4`. The first upgrade is just buying the building.

Gates when transformed stay the same level as the wall they started as, can still be upgraded.

Every bot starts with five health, one damage, and three sight radius. They can upgrade each by four for the cost of `1/2/2/2`.

All upgrades take one bot. It takes `1/2/2/3` turns to upgrade an item. The bot must upgrade the item all at once or it must restart and repay the cost. Building a item takes one resource.

Comment: so, how does turn order work? is there a way to attack excluding turrets?

Comment: Will the bots have knowledge of the entire 1000x1000 area or what is the line of sight?

Comment: I'd recommend not making the challenge too complicated/complex. I'm not sure that skill points are necessary.

Comment: How does it work with the Q&A site format? Or is it an off-site challenge?

Comment: @ugoren King of the Hill challenges like this one are very much on-topic on PPCG, and in fact we even have a tag for challenges like these: [tag:koth].

Comment: @Cowsquack, You're right, it's OK. A bit strange for my taste, since the war happens off-site, but never mind.

Comment: @SimonForsberg good point

Comment: This will not be a challenge between PPCG and CR. [Challenge declined](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8387/31562)

Comment: Since this idea is dead now, consider developing it further as a normal KoTH or deleting and editing it down to a stub.

Answer (score 5):

## Swap the frogs!

Given 2 integers `N >= 1`, representing left-side frogs, and `M >= 1`, representing right-side frogs, return all the steps required so that the frogs change sides with the minimum number of steps. The frogs start with one empty spot between the two sides. A frog can jump to the empty space if there is at most 1 frog from either side between the frog and the empty space. A frog can jump either forwards or backwards.

---

An example, with `N = 3` and `M = 2`:

```
LLL.RR
LL.LRR
LLRL.R
LLRLR.
LLR.RL
L.RLRL
.LRLRL
RL.LRL
RLRL.L
RLR.LL
R.RLLL
RR.LLL
```

The corresponding output would be (1-indexed):

```
[3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3]
```

Each one is the index of the column that the frog that must jump is before jumping.

## Rules

- You may perform I/O in any reasonable format.

Comment: Maybe start with a small example, because now the main output specification is tucked under a huge block of text, which will be TL;DR for many people.

Comment: 1. The questions in the section headed "*Sandbox*" make no sense because their context has been deleted. Are they still relevant? 2. "*What you have to print*" should presumably be "*What you have to output*". 3. "*A frog can jump either forwards or backwards*" so there should be at least one test case where all optimal paths only involve jumping forwards and at least one where all optimal paths involve jumping backwards.

Comment: Maybe a testcase where no steps are necessary, too.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Please, don't be too meta :-) :p

Answer (score 5):

## Learning your strengths and weaknesses [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

- Fighters have a unique, random Strength (between 1 and 1000)
- When two fighters fight, the stronger one wins.
- Your goal is to accurately guess your fighter's Strength.

### Gameplay:

1. We start by randomly ordering all 1000 fighters.
2. Each fighter fights his neighbor (The even fighters fight the fighter 1 above)
3. The fighter is given two pieces of information:  His opponent's last guess, and who won the fight.  The fighter then guesses his strength.
4. We perform a stable sort based on the guessed strength, and go back to step 2
5. After 10 guesses, the fighter's score is `(RealStrength - GuessedStrength)^2`.  Lower is better.

## Other details:

- There will be duplicate bots in a single game.
- A stable sort is a sort that (effectively) uses the past ordering as a tiebreaker.  In essence, if players `[A,B,C,D]` guessed `[10,5,10,5]` then the new order would be `[B,D,A,C]`
- Bots aren't allowed to share information between each other, but are allowed to persist information within a single game.
- I will run a large number of games.  The exact number will be dependent on how much variation there is.  Your final score will be all of your scores summed up.

Comment: I like this a lot. Sounds like a very interesting challenge. A couple thoughts though. 1) What's the point of squaring your score? If there was some kind of polynomial scoring I could see that, but it doesn't really have any purpose at the moment. 2) personally, I think it should be more than 10 rounds.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I think 10 rounds is enough for good bots to get a reasonable score without providing so much information that many will get a perfect score. I do think the process should be repeated though. Maybe a terminology change: 10 *guesses* per round, each round scored as indicated, average of X rounds is the final score. Also, the squaring is a way of getting absolute value (result is always positive even if guess > real) and if averaging multiple results it weights wildly incorrect guesses to increase the score by a lot.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Squaring means that being 50 off is *far* worse than being 25 off.    I picked 10 rounds because log2(1000) is 9.97.  This requires bots to be efficient with their time. If I make it much higher, then its going to be hard for me to differentiate the top bots.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Updated, thanks.

Comment: In step 3, each fighter is provided "His opponent's last guess". What will be provided during the first round?

Comment: That'll be part of the API spec.  Something like -1.

Comment: This will probably be my last suggestion (for now): a link and/or description for "stable sort" will probably be helpful; I certainly needed to look it up, and is quite useful for informing strategies, as well as answering a question I otherwise had about handling ties.

Answer (score 5):

## Efficient Tab Completion

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Many tools that programmers use on a daily basis, like bash and Emacs, have [*tab completion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion).

- Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in certain situations will attempt to complete the text at the cursor, from a set of possibilities. The term is "completed" by filling in the remaining text.
- For the aforementioned, if there are multiple candidates for completion, you will instead be shown a list of the candidates.
- If there are multiple possibilities but they all start with the same substring/prefix, the rest of that substring will be filled in.

For example, to reach `pydoc3`, you only have to type

```
pyd<TAB>3
```

where <kbd>Tab</kbd> is shown as `<TAB>`. The tab key will insert `oc`, since all options starting with `pyd` also start with `pydoc` <sub>(in the set below)</sub>.

[image: a shot of bash tab completion options]

---

### The Challenge

Given a **collection of strings** called *S* and a **target string** called *T*, figure out the minimum number of keystrokes to reach *T*, assuming we're using tab completion and *S* is the set of possibilities.

- Tab completion here is modeled after bash and Emacs, so it is case-sensitive.
- The keystrokes/moves don't matter, only how many. A "keystroke" is:

  - Some character in the string
  - <kbd>Tab</kbd>
  - If *S* is `[abc, ab]` and *T* is `ab`, then either `a<TAB>` or `ab` will get there. <kbd>Tab</kbd> counts as one keystroke, so the method doesn't matter.
- You may assume terms will only contain alphanumeric characters, underscore, and hyphen (`[A-Za-z0-9]_-`), for the purpose of this challenge.
- You may assume no strings are empty.
- You may assume *S* contains *T* (**unsure about this one**)
- The input can be taken in whatever format is appropriate for your platform or language (array of strings, string with separators etc.) *S* and *T* are considered separate inputs.

  - I/O format is flexible and defaults apply (full program, function etc.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

---

### Test Cases

```
Set                                                 Target         Output
--------------------------------------------------  -------------  ------
[ab, abc]                                           ab             2
[lisp-mode, list-abbrevs, list-packages]            list-packages  5
[heck, hell, help_me, hello, goodbye, hello_world]  hello          5
```

---

### Feedback

- Is anything vague or underspecified?
- Is something *too* specific or cumbersome?
- Is this too similar to an existing question?
- Should we assume *S* will always contain *T*, or require a special case?
- Should something be changed about case-sensitivity? Assume everything is lowercase?
- Any tags I should use?

Comment: Hmm. wouldn't it be `l<TAB>t-p<TAB>` for #2? Also how to get `hello` in 4 keystrokes?

Comment: You're right about `list-packages`, I'll fix it. And it looks like `hello` should be 5 keystrokes at `hello`. Good eye.

Comment: You can get symbols for keys using `<kbd>` (<kbd>tab</kbd>)

Comment: I like this challenge! A couple of questions: is it illegal to start typing with a TAB (could be useful when all the strings in S start with the same prefix)? Why is `.` not in the allowed characters, since it is present in your first example of pydoc?

Comment: You can use `<TAB>` wherever you want as long as it produces the minimum keystrokes. The image is supposed to be illustrative and not necessarily representative of the challenge itself; I worry that requiring too large or too specific a subset of characters will make the challenge more complicated than it needs to be (or maybe it won't affect much at all?)

Comment: Assume S is `[abcde]` and T is `abcdf`. What should be the output?

Answer (score 5):

## [Existential Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168528/)

Comment: Proofs could be simple: it supports NAND, and NAND is functionally complete.

Comment: @tsh Currently there is still no winning criteria.

Comment: This is quite interesting (not sarcasm!), but what's the actual challenge?

Comment: @Nathaniel When I actually finish it this will be the next installment of [tag:proof-golf].

Comment: It's great to see an unfinished idea, ready for feedback until it's postable. I see this as an important purpose of the sandbox.

Comment: @trichoplax [Not everyone think so](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43776183#43776183).

Comment: I definitely disagree with having to make sandbox posts "finished". I agree with not being lazy though. I see this post as a great example of unlazy and unfinished (when posted). There was clearly effort made, and it was made available for feedback early, which can avoid going too far down a path that others already know won't work. Posting early prunes impossible or impractical challenges so challenge authors have more time for writing the challenges that will make it to main.

Comment: @user202729 For context, I said that in response to a 1-sentence sandbox post. I also said it bothers me when people *"just post the bare minimum they can get by with and edit it later"*. The first revision of this challenge was clearly not *the bare minimum to get by with*.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem So you're measuring effort? That's usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

## Split and recombine a number

This [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge has two related parts. Your task is to write two functions/programs as per the below specifications. You may share code across your submissions, the submissions may call one another, and you may even submit a single submission which handles both conversions. In the latter case, conversion direction may be determined by whether the input is a single number vs a list, or by an additional consistent second value (not a function) input.

### Part 1

Given a floating point number, return a list with one element per digit of its integer part, if any, and if the number is a non-integer, one additional part which is the fractional part. If the number is negative, negate all elements in the output. If the number is zero, return a 1-element list with a zero in it.

When the result list is recombined as per Part 2, it must be precise to within an absolute or relative error of 10⁻¹⁰, whichever is more permissive.

### Part 2

Given a list generated as per Part 1, return the number which would have generated that list in Part 1.

When the result number is split as per Part 1, each element must be precise to within an absolute or relative error of 10⁻¹⁰, whichever is more permissive.

### Examples

```
Part 1 <-> Part 2
-123       [-1,-2,-3]
2.71828    [2,0.71828]
-800.6     [-8,0,0,-0.6]
321.7001   [3,2,1,0.7001]
-0.01      [-0.01]
100        [1,0,0]
0          [0]
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode) [decode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decode)

Comment: (1) Technically infinities are floating point numbers (or, at least, they're not NaNs). What should the output be for an infinity? (2) How about for 1E45? (3) For numbers which are small enough to have a fractional part, what restrictions are there on the precision of the output? E.g. to take the fourth test case, `321.7001 - 321` in IEEE 754 double format gives `0.7001000000000204`.

Comment: Do we need the leading 0 in the list? Seems cleaner without it

Comment: @Quintec What leading zero?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'll exclude infinities. I'm not sure what do do about inexactness. I guess I could allow stopping at 16 digits of precision. Any ideas?

Comment: Now that I think about it, string output for part one doesn’t make sense. But if it did, then I meant [2, .718] instead of [2, 0.718]

Comment: I don't see any reason to reject `0 <-> []`, given that `0.01 <-> [0.01]`.

Comment: For the precision, how about something in the line of "correct up to absolute/relative precision of `1e-16`"? Partly because big numbers stored in double are not accurate even in the integer parts.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, I'll add that. Also, see tolerance text now.

Comment: @Bubbler Tolerance specs added.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `4.4 <-> [4,0.4]` and `44.44 <-> [4,4,0.44]`. Also, can we assume there will not be any unnecessary trailing zeros? I have a working solution, even with workaround for `0 <-> [0]`, but for `0.0` it outputs `[0.0]`, but vice-versa for `[0.0]` it outputs `0` instead of `0.0`. Hence the question that there won't be test cases like `0.0`, `4.0` or `6.4000` with unnecessary trailing zeros. My programming language outputs `4.0 -> [4,0] -> 40` due to the implicit conversion of `0.0` to `0`..

Comment: @Adám FWIW Composed a solution using JavaScript for the specification at this question, and a solution for the specification at the original question (that currently has a bug for two test cases at "Part 2" portion, though is not incapable of being fixed).

Answer (score 5):

> Progress: Updated the rules again, and also add the timed function to the bots.

## Sylver Coinage KotH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

[Sylver Coinage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage) is a 2-player mathematical game that has the following rules:

1. Two players take turns announcing a natural number each time.
2. Each number announced must be unrepresentable as the sum of non-negative multiples of the numbers announced before.

   > Eg. if the first three numbers announced are \$\{6, 11, 15\}\$, then you cannot announce any numbers representable as \$6n_1+11n_2+15n_3\$, where \$n_1,n_2,n_3\ge0\$. You can announce, for example, \$16\$, though.
3. The player who announced a number not complying with Rule 2, or the number 1, loses.

Here is a twist -- R. L. Hutchings proved that announcing a prime number as the first play provides a winning strategy for the first player, although the detail of the strategy is not yet known. <s>So I put a restriction here: **the first player cannot announce a prime number in the first step.**</s> Now the first two numbers will be generated randomly by the driver at the beginning. No more restriction on prime numbers now.

### Technical Information

A bot playing the game will have to implement a Python 3 class, extending `TimedBot`, with two methods: `announce()` and `learn()`. `announce()` should receive a list of numbers (possibly empty) and return a single integer, and `learn()` should receive two integers (id of the first move and second move) and the complete list of the numbers in the last game played.

Here is a sample implementation. **Note: DO NOT use this as your submission -- this sample only serves as a demonstration, and it may announce numbers that violate Rule 2.**

```python
class SampleBot(TimedBot):     # must not be changed.
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()     # must not be changed.
        self.id = id

    def announce(self, list):
        import random
        return random.randint(1, 101)

    def learn(self, first, second, list):
        pass
```

#### [Test Drive](https://tio.run/##rVRNj9owEL37V0zZi816acLeVsuq6g/opb2hCJnEWSwlTuoYEEL72@nYCYkDLFKr5gDJfLw38zzj@mA3lX4@ndJCNA38UqXMvlf2hQA@mcxhtVJa2dWKNrLIWWt3j/ucWQyHBcyjWUT6DGfMaL7VaRDuHLnH4DAV5r0JfO5RZV0Z63NHdoHwzuipKBv51uhzNCPYUcRQ5NMCaIADTyDGobVR2tI@Yew00m6NhjW5MOSEtLr9FGVdSBSOnhVkn0jIQWWhjNtaGspmfQwbK6wybFJlrbrfzuC@xKwnEFpXqIPsCArV2ICik9YInVXlZQetdeb@XP8xhzjCJ2b3GQspjO7ocmUay7HctNLZFXuN8hDyADtpDqC0zHOVKqktcTCqKdAkTFqVa6oxt0tUjkHTIsDJKwMKAVzF75JGHDQ8AtZbLKPkcpgQGRYL0GNz0PZSw9evPjUZhciip4Y3iK/zsWJ3IKO6cZiUqyN@Sdh1gu/yGigsRvXFYEsYTQLnj0pLQoqqcYv2FBNvXEBE9LZs8GWZkHVl/dswhBHjwUjGLIEHxKsLkUrYK7uBQ7U14PM20sgZIeMh2W9UIYE6IRwNg1eYdxoLDmsOKQc3mLemB6n/g/k8BvPpVMAUnqfTNXxZuM@0/cxw6rOR@60d3ejs6AMvHaXSVPCUtX73teaZP@/5cE5neQMGHqImnUj@ZF4hajN3mOJkXbpjSmb9YnoVyXDPTI7RBz3GH6zf3QyO84/JDMe8FJbaQy3pAOTuBy1KuVrxEF7huu1Yi7u/HMsdh4EVldwHl441GD2Z3Fmu/uhvrNb1MDvAR0R8nJBbZmx2is323TngpUo47PG33dZXz7hnuIGoZzTs0V29wG6ExbZB/t6KAmwFx@d/EpG7WtnA2u2biyD9vbBzd0pwJ3xeWvzXNdzh9pOIMi537V3V3QAxXjs@5rKMvdLNDX4X76Cva@g9vo7T6Q8)

```python
class TimedBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = 20.0

    def timed(func):
        def f(self, *args):
            import time
            a = time.time()
            b = func(self, *args)
            self.time -= (time.time() - a)
            print(self.time)
            return b
        return f

class SampleBot(TimedBot):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id

    @TimedBot.timed
    def announce(self, list):
        import random
        return random.randint(1, 100001)

    @TimedBot.timed
    def learn(self, first, second, list):
        pass

# very inefficient
def islinearcomb(n, l):
    if len(l):
        for i in range(0, n + 1, l[0]):
            if i == n:
                return [n // l[0]]
            elif len(l) > 1:
                isl = islinearcomb(n - i, l[1:])
                if isl:
                    return [i // l[0]] + isl
    return None

lose = -1
turn = 0
nums = []
bots = [SampleBot(0), SampleBot(1)] # replace with your bots here.

import random
while (len(nums) < 2):
    a, b, c, d = random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)
    if 2**a * 3**b != 2**c * 3**d and 2**a * 3**b > 100000 and 2**c * 3**d > 100000 and 2**min(a,c) * 3**min(b,d) > 12:
        nums = [2**a * 3**b, 2**c * 3**d]
while lose < 0:
    v = bots[turn].announce(nums)
    print("{0}({1}) announced {2}".format(type(bots[turn]).__name__, bots[turn].id, v))
    w = islinearcomb(v, nums)
    if w:
        str = ""
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            if i:
                str += "+"
            str += "{0}*{1}".format(nums[i], w[i] if i < len(w) else 0)
        print("{0}({1}) announced {2} that is equal to {3}".format(type(bots[turn]).__name__, bots[turn].id, v, str))
        lose = turn
    elif v == 1:
        print("{0}({1}) announced 1".format(type(bots[turn]).__name__, bots[turn].id))
        lose = turn
    nums += [v]
    turn = 1 - turn
print("{0}({1}) wins".format(type(bots[1 - lose]).__name__, bots[1 - lose].id))
```

### Restrictions

Each bot will have 20 seconds of time for deciding a move `todo: adjustments`. Running out time during the move results in a lose, and failing to finish a method within 20 seconds will lead to disqualification and rerun of all 100 rounds with the remaining bots.

### Schedule

Submissions will be open until `todo: date here`. After that 100 complete round-robin rounds will be done. Each pair of bots will compete twice in each round, one with the first bot announcing first, and one with the second bot announcing first. Each win brings 3 points, each draw brings 1 point, and each lose brings no points. The bot with the highest points after 100 rounds wins. The tiebreaker will be as follows:

1. Points got
2. Wins achieved
3. Drawing lots

Comment: Probably needs some time limit for responses to prevent solutions which attempt to generate a full game tree.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh yes I thought about the time limit but I turned out forgetting to put that ;p

Comment: "*The player who announced a number not complying with Rule 2 ... loses.*" I've been thinking about this. I presume that your intention is that the controller will validate the responses. An alternative would be to say that you don't *automatically* lose, but to add a type of response where the bot can return a proof that the opponent broke rule 2. Then bot programmers have to make a decision as to how much time to spend trying to show that their opponent lost vs computing a valid response.

Comment: What if a game goes on for a billion turns?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd say my intention is that the controller will validate the responses. (in the test drive there is the code doing exactly that)

Comment: @isaacg If the number does not start out too large a game should end quite quickly. It is because two coprime numbers already make the number of possible moves finite. But If I pose a criteria on how large a number can at most go, then I'm feared that there may be a problem that the game tree is restricted.

Comment: I'd say: don't restrict the highest move, but give each bot a 'chess clock': they start with (say) 10s, and gain 1 second per move (and pass their clock's time as a parameter).  Running over time is an automatic loss, and some percentage of time losses is a disqualification.  Playing high moves will quickly exhaust their stock of time if they attempt to calculate extensive game trees, which will force the bots to either play quickly or lower their numbers.  Adding a decay function to the time per move will encourage smart bots to play smaller numbers to not run out of time to think.

Comment: @Spitemaster That's a good idea, but what I concerned about on large numbers is that the validation may take too long (because we are solving Diophantine equations in many unknowns)

Comment: Do you realise that guaranteeing that the first two numbers are coprime guarantees that the first player will win with correct play? If you want an interesting game then you should generate the first two numbers randomly as 3-smooth numbers with a GCD which is a multiple of 6 and greater than 12.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Great catch! During discussion only the suggestion of giving two initial numbers was achieved, so I didn't realize that.

Comment: I would remove the submission deadline, why not keep it open and update once a new entry comes? Also you might be interested in [this](https://gist.github.com/bforte/4695ad7b9b7f245b328114869ece2e4e) (I adapted the code originally written for another KoTH), the easiest thing will be to enforce a certain formatting on the first line and adapt `code_matcher` to that formatting, st. that it won't break because everyone is using different formatting.

Comment: @BMO Wow that's a good one! And I saw my code in the source lol BTW for the `certain formatting` part you mean the lines around `class FooBar(TimedBot):`?

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto: Yeah, I added the header to `bots.py` which will be used, all the users' code will be appended to that and written to `auto_bots.py`.. Basically you'll only need to checkout the few variables (lines 12-20) and the main (from line 117) to see how it works. About the formatting, yes, that's probably the most sane: Make sure every code starts with `class NameOfBot(TimedBot):`, all definitions are in that class and it's valid Python 3 code (I updated the `code_matcher` like this it should work fine).

Comment: If they/you use that `bots.py` you'll need to manually update the imports or do it inside the bot itself, atm. bots could use `random` and `time`, maybe add `math` too.

Answer (score 5):

## Interleave Invariance

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

There is an infinite sequence that does not change when interleaved with the natural numbers. Consider these few terms:

```
1 1 2 1 3 2 4 1
```

Interleave them with the naturals:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
  1   1   2   1   3   2   4   1
-------------------------------
1 1 2 1 3 2 4 1 5 3 6 2 7 4 8 1
```

As you can see, there is no change in the initial eight. Now, this sequence can be extended indefinitely rather easily by repeating this interleave operation. Your task is to choose and implement one of three output formats:

1. Take as input a nonnegative integer `n` and output the `n`th term of this sequence, zero- or one-indexed (your choice).
2. Take as input a nonnegative integer `n` and output the first `n` terms of this sequence.
3. Output terms in order forever, starting from the beginning.

For options 2 and 3, there must be no numeric characters and at least one non-numeric character between terms; this separator need not be consistent. `1+1=2` would be fine for input 3. Leading and trailing non-numeric characters are allowed.

Here are the first 64 terms. This is OEIS sequence [A003602](http://oeis.org/A003602).

```
1 1 2 1 3 2 4 1 5 3 6 2 7 4 8 1 9 5 10 3 11 6 12 2 13 7 14 4 15 8 16 1 17 9 18 5 19 10 20 3 21 11 22 6 23 12 24 2 25 13 26 7 27 14 28 4 29 15 30 8 31 16 32 1
```

Your submission can be a program or a function; "input" and "output" are [as defined by the community](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) are forbidden.

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest solution (in bytes) wins! Good luck, and happy golfing!

---

## Sandboxy Stuff

Am I clear enough on what the sequence is? Any suggestions for rewording?

Is this a duplicate? I've searched for "interleave" and "3602" and found nothing.

Anything else worth mentioning? What thoughts ya gots?

Thanks to Martin Ender for the output formats, taken almost straight from the Kolakoski challenge.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66031/converging-sums-of-a-fractal-sequence) (not a dupe though)

Comment: You could consider removing the option to output just the n'th term, making answers output a sequence. Otherwise I think it will be shortest in most languages to take `n`, halve until non-whole, then add 1/2 (ceiling), rather than use the interleaving property which I think is cooler.

Comment: It looks like `n/(n&-n)/2+1` would work for a lot of languages such as Python.

Comment: @xnor Do you think removing that option will help much? I can't really think of a case where the solution won't be to wrap your expression in a looping construct if the expression was the shortest. I don't think knowing the history of this function is that helpful to finding the future value.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman You're probably right, answers would mostly just do the expression in some loop. In Haskell I think the interleaving definition wins out (even with option 1 allowed), but maybe that's just Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

### Evaluate C−− expression [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Your goal is to a evaluate an expression in "C−−" (not [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--)) which uses only the characters are `C` and `-`. `C` is an variable holding an integer whose initial value you're given, and the `-` symbol is used in many ways including as a [decrement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators):

- `C--` decrements the value stored in `C`, then evaluates to that value.
- `--C` evaluates to `C`, then decrements the value stored in `C`.
- `-expr` negates the value of the expression `expr`.
- `expr1-expr2` takes the difference of the two expressions.

Unfortunately, the C−− specification doesn't state how expressions are parsed or in what order parts are evaluated, saying these are "implementation dependent". So, it's up to you. For example, `--C---C` could be interpreted as `-(-(C--)-C)` or `(--C)-(--C)` or others, and each `--C` might be evaluated before or after other parts of the expression.

**Input:** A string consisting of `C` and `-`, and an integer initial value for `C`.

The string will be parseable in at least one way. You can take the string as a list of characters, but they must be exactly the characters `C` and `-`.

**Output:** A value this expression could evaluate to.

You don't need to worry about issues with overly large values like overflows or loss of precision.

TODO: test cases

Comment: Can `--C---C ` be parsed as `-(-(C-(-(-C))))`?

Comment: @H.PWiz Yes. Unfortunately, it looks like as is `--C`, can always be interpreted as `-(-C)`, which is golfier but more boring, so I'll probably restrict the parsing or removing the unary negation option.

Comment: @xnor Note: `-C` is the same as `(C-C)-C`, but there are no parentheses here so nobody can say it can't also be parsed as `C-(C-C)`. An added rule can be "You can't parse `--C` as `-(-C)`, as a double negation would be meaningless."

Comment: Do you want to include or exclude simple eval implementations?

Comment: @PhilH That's a good question. Eval-style solutions seems pretty boring for C-style languages, but I don't know if there's a clean way to even specify what would be disallowed. I don't have time to work on this challenge, so you're welcome to spruce it up and post it if you want.

Comment: if the C-- in question is *not* the one linked, could you link the one you're referring to? You mentioned a C-- specification, so I assume there is one

Comment: @Skidsdev I meant it as a thing I'm making up for the challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## An Auction in St. Petersburg

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### Setup

Mysterious packages are up for auction today. These boxes are unique in that their values are not known until they are opened, and when they are opened, their values follow a unique distribution:

```
probability    value
0.5               $2
0.25              $4
0.125             $8
0.0625           $16
1/(2^n)       $(2^n)
```

In total, there are 100 such packages up for auction, to be sold sequentially. At the start, each bot arrives with $20 in their wallet, and the goal is to walk away with more money than anyone else.

During each round in the auction, each bot simultaneously submits a bid. The bot with the highest bid (ties broken randomly) must pay the value of the second-highest bid, after which that winning bot receives an amount of money corresponding to the value of the opened package. This money can then be "reinvested" in future rounds of the auction.

The auction day ends once all 100 packages have been sold, or when any bot's wallet value exceeds 2^31.

### I/O format

As input, your bot receives the following info:

- an array of everyone's current wallet amounts
- the history of past sale prices (the amount paid, not highest amount bid) and winners

As output, your bot returns an integer between 0 and your current wallet amount.

### Tournament format

There will be N=large number of game run according to the above format (100 auction rounds each), and the finishing position of the bots will be averaged across games.

Comment: Could you explain why it ends when someone reaches 2^31?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl It's mostly to prevent players from having to deal with numbers that don't fit into a 32-bit integer. There's only a 1 in 1 billion chance that a particular package will contain enough money to trigger this condition, I just wanted to clarify how I would handle the "infinite expected value" in practice.

Comment: This seems rather win-more. It just takes one big win to be able to guarantee that you can outbid everyone else for the rest of the game.

Answer (score 5):

## Fix my stuttered words

Posted: [Fix my stuttered words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193196/81663)

Comment: "_You can assume that multiple valid sets of repeated stuttered words only happen from left to right, so fixing "**op op op o o o open**" would result in "**op op op open**"._" Shouldn't this result in "**op open**" instead? In the first rule you mention "_For example "**ope**" and "**open**" both can be a stuttered word for "**open**"._" So since the entire word is valid as stutter, I would think "**op op op o o o open**" becomes `"([op op] op) ([o o o] open)"` (`([this] ... )` being the stutter, and `([...] this)` being the word), thus "**op open**".

Comment: I think you meant to give the example "_... so fixing "**op op o o o open**" would result in "**op op open**"._" (so one less `op`) instead?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: You are absolutely correct, I have updated the question. Thank you for reading with such a high precision.

Answer (score 5):

## [Score a 1 player game of Carcassonne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205861/66833)

Comment: @dingledooper I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: What I mean is, there are some tiles with roads going in more than one direction, so your scoring method seems to suggest that the same tile can be scored more than once. This is different than the official rules, which state that every tile may only be scored once.

Comment: @dingledooper The rules state, when referring to scoring a road, "each tile of **that** road grants you 1 point" (emphasis mine). To me, that implies that a tile containing sections of multiple roads can be scored for each of those roads

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up for me. The only reason I asked was because it contrasted from the way I played Carcassonne (or how it is normally played).

Comment: The scoring for incomplete road seems to have at least one incorrect word. Also, how are monasteries represented in your input format?

Comment: Or indeed villages.

Comment: @Neil Yes, it does, thanks for spotting that. The monastery tiles are `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`. As no other tile can be described by these two, I didn’t think it would be necessary to add an additional value representing a monastery. It’s similar with villages; each of the tiles with a village on is unique without having to specify that it has a village on it. For instance, the tile `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]` (a rotation of `[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`) is guaranteed to have a village on it, so another value is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, so a tile with at least 3 roads always has a village, and a tile with no features apart from an optional single road always has a monastery?

Comment: @Neil Yes exactly

Answer (score 5):

### Add the quotes [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Background

There's a terrible problem in my console - the quotes never get included inside the arguments! So, when given this argument:

```
["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
```

it says that the argument is like this:

```
[abc,def,ghi,jkl]
```

It would be very nice if you can fix this problem!

### Body

Add double-quotes (`"`) in order to surround a word (i.e. something that matches `[a-z]+`).

```
[[one, two, three],
[one, two, three],
[one, two, three],
[one, two, three]]
```

### Test cases

```
[abc,def,ghi,jkl] -> ["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
this is a test    -> "this" "is" "a" "test"
test              -> "test"
this "one" "contains' "quotations -> "this" ""one"" ""contains"' ""quotations"
But This One Is SpeciaL! -> B"ut" T"his" O"ne" I"s" S"pecia"L!
```

### Rules for the input

- The words are never capitalized.

Comment: Suggested test case: one that starts (and/or ends) with a word (i.e. `this is a test` -> `"this" "is" "a" "test"`).

Comment: Another suggested test case: a single word without anything else (i.e. `test` -> `"test"`).

Comment: An issue here is that since this  I/O is strict, many languages can't actually execute it. GolfScript, for example, can't take in letters in any ways that isn't in quotations.

Comment: @Mathgeek No you can - do you know that GolfScript takes the whole STDIN as a string? [Example.](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkPBNHR@XmpOgol5flAIqMoNTVWh4tMoVgA)

Comment: Perhaps some testcases that already contain quotes

Comment: You have to escape them: `[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\"]`

Comment: Is this challenge not simply a regex substitution; 22 bytes in vim: `:%s/\([a-z]\+\)/"\1"/g`?

Answer (score 5):

### Is the input Bl lu ur rr ry? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

This is based off [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203893/bl-lu-ur-rr-ry-yv-vi-is-si-io-on-blur-the-text/) challenge.

Given an input string, check whether the string is blurry.

### What's a blurry string?

Take a non-blurrified string `abc` as an example. You repeat every character of this twice:

```
aabbcc
```

And then insert spaces at every odd-even index.

```
a ab bc c
```

Then, remove the preceding 2 and succeeding 2 extra characters.

```
ab bc
```

As an example, all of these strings are blurry (the empty line stands for an empty string):

```
"a"   ->
"ab"  ->ab
"abc" ->ab bc
"abcd"->ab bc cd
...
```

### Specification

- The input string consists purely of printable ASCII characters. The only whitespace it will contain is the space character.
- You don't have to remove extra characters before the check.
- Your output can consist of any trailing whitespace, as long as it's possible to tell a truthy result from a falsy result.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a@kxKWUmAQmFJKSYbRCcgqQqYBgQkUVlLiAbDAfqhYkDFOinJSsDGUmJUMYCkjGATlgrgLIuqREheQkhZRkCBOoBMx0c0tMzMkpLk5NVeLS5Dq39f@hZYdWGB/ecm6r0bmdCcWHu4sPbwhUqz08/3/tfwA) is a program I use to check my test cases.

```
""          -> True
"ab"        -> True
"ab bc"     -> True
"ab bc cd"  -> True
" b bc cd"  -> True
"ab bc c "  -> True
"a   c cd"  -> True

"a"         -> False
"abc"       -> False
"ab  bc  cd"-> False
"ab#bc#cd"  -> False
"abbccd"    -> False
"a ab bc cd"-> False
"a a ab b b"-> False
"ba cb dc"  -> False
"ba bc dc"  -> False
"FFaallssee"-> False
```

Comment: Shouldn't the reverse version be "un-blur the string"? This is more like a decision-problem version of the blur challenge.

Comment: This Challenge to Blurry Vision is like Narcissist to Quine.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Uh-blur the string seems too easy, therefore I made it a decision problem. So can you find a duplicate for this?

Comment: I think you meant "un-blur". No, this is probably not a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it double speak?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak)

Comment: @mathjunkie Not really. This challenge is about consecutive characters separated by consistent spaces. (The spaces may or may not be there.)

Comment: @petStorm Yeah, I guess it's different enough

Answer (score 5):

## Draw a Peano Curve with Slashes

Given a positive integer N, draw the N<sup>th</sup> iteration of the [Peano Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve), using only slashes and backslashes (and spaces).  The curve will be rotated at a 45 degree angle from its usual depiction.  Here's an example for the first 3 iterations:

N = 1

```
 /\
/ /
 / /
 \/
```

N = 2

```
       /\
      / /
     / / /\
    /  \/ /
   / /\  / /\
   \/ /  \/ /
 /\  / /\  / /\
/ / / / / / / /
 / / / / / / / /
 \/ /  \/ /  \/
   / /\  / /\
   \/ /  \/ /
     / /\  /
     \/ / /
       / /
       \/
```

N = 3

```
                         /\
                        / /
                       / / /\
                      /  \/ /
                     / /\  / /\
                     \/ /  \/ /
                   /\  / /\  / /\
                  / / / / / / / /
                 / / / / / / / / /\
                /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
               / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
               \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
             /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
            / / / / /  \/ / / / / / / /
           / / / / / /\  / / / / / / / /\
          /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
         / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
         \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
       /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
      / /  \/ / / / / / / /  \/ / / / / / / / 
     / / /\  / / / / / / / /\  / / / / / / / /\
    /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
   / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
   \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
 /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
 / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
 \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/
   / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\
   \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /
     / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  /
     \/ / / / / / / /  \/ / / / / / / /  \/ / /
       / / / / / / / /\  / / / / / / / /\  / / 
       \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/  
         / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\    
         \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /    
           / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\  /     
           \/ / / / / / / /  \/ / / / / /      
             / / / / / / / /\  / / / / /       
             \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/        
               / /\  / /\  / /\  / /\          
               \/ /  \/ /  \/ /  \/ /         
                 / /\  / /\  / /\  /
                 \/ / / / / / / / /
                   / / / / / / / /
                   \/ /  \/ /  \/
                     / /\  / /\
                     \/ /  \/ /
                       / /\  /
                       \/ / /
                         / /
                         \/
```

You may optionally mirror this horizontally, vertically, or both if you choose.  Leading spaces are clearly required for this.  Trailing spaces are optional.  This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

Comment: Is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34852/draw-the-hilbert-curve-using-slashes) what you were looking for? It seems like a direct duplicate.

Comment: @dingledooper Ah, crud.  I did a search and everything and that didn't come up.  Maybe because it's too old or something.  Oh well - should I just delete this then?  Could switch it to the Peano or Gosper Curve, but I don't know if that would be appreciably different.

Comment: The Gosper curve is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50521/ascii-art-of-the-day-2-flow-snakes. The Peano curve doesn't seem to be a duplicate, but I'm not sure whether it's a good idea.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I changed it to the Peano Curve, might still be interesting to do.

Answer (score 5):

## Posted: [Scoring Quantum Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206342/scoring-quantum-tic-tac-toe)

Comment: Do `cyclic entanglement` always have len=3?

Comment: @l4m2 A cyclic entanglement can have any length provided it fits on the board. For instance, in the case `DE AB DE 1 AH CF CH CG BC 2`, there is a loop of length 4 across `A`, `B`, `C` and `H`. I will make a note of this in the challenge.

Comment: @l4m2 In that same case, there is also a loop of length 2: `DE .. DE`

Comment: I don't think the description directly states that the *other* player chooses the state in all cases

Comment: Can describing what state was chosen be done in other ways? For example, writing the number of the mark that fills the cell of the last quantum mark placed might be useful instead of the lowest cell alphabetically.

Comment: @fireflame241 Yes, you can choose to describe the state chosen in whatever way is convenient (I added your example to the "rules" section). And thanks for pointing that out about who chooses the state, it's clear now I hope

Comment: In your illustration, does the position of the quantum marks in a single cell (e.g. in your second picture, the center cell has three marks arranged in a J shape) matter?

Comment: @Trebor It does not, noted

Comment: Is it possible input go on there after result comes?

Comment: @l4m2 No: "A game continues until at least one tic-tac-toe is formed or until the board is filled with classical marks." I will add that no more moves can be done after this and that multiple tic-tac-toes can only be formed simultaneously

Answer (score 5):

## My smart phone

Posted here:
[My smartphone's phonebook](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210262/my-smartphones-phonebook)

Comment: I like this idea. Just to make sure I've understood the challenge correctly, given a phone number, are we to find all possible strings that match it within a database of strings?

Comment: Not quite. Given a database/list of strings, split these by space into _words_. Return all database entries that contain a _word_ that matches the number.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/implement-t9-like-functionality)

Comment: This question only asks return entries consisting of one word, while this asks to check for possibly multiple words per entry and then to return the complete entry.  
Also, this quesition had unusual and harsh restrictions. This aims to be much more simpler than that, making the puzzle more attractive. While the first reason may be splitting hairs, the second one, combined with the puzzle being ~6 yrs old, is a good reason to post this puzzle, imo.

Comment: Add my name in!

Comment: 'You may only take input in some form of list type, not a string.' Rigid I/O requirements are generally [frowned upon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/92901).

Comment: True, no idea why I insisted on that. I'd rather not have this challenge killed because of a probably useless constraint.

Comment: You've probably thought of this, but you could get more names from [Users](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation). (I'm chuffed to have already made the cut, by the way!) Is there a mistake in the `34` test case - wouldn't `HighlyRadioactive` appear under `44`?

Comment: whoops... fixed. I'll add some more people from Users when posting, for the test cases I've just listed some people I see a lot off the top of my head. Also, if you gave some feedback, there's no reason not to put you in there.

Comment: Why is fireflame241 there twice?

Comment: Third-Party 'Chef' is now called petStorm - update.

Answer (score 5):

## [Build an alphabetised polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209669/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## [Implement the random Fibonacci sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211166/66833)

Comment: Is -3 a valid output for f5?

Comment: But it is possible that f3 = 2. It is also possible that f4 = -1.

Comment: @tsh It is possible that f3 = 2 and it is possible that f4 = -1, but the two cannot be satisfied at once. So the challenge requires to record the previous results, I think (and therefore some short approaches like naive recursion can't be used).

Comment: It would be good to include the correct distributions of the first few entries, like f_3 to f_6, for testing purposes.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing f3 = f2 + f1 = 1 + 1 = 2; f4 = f3 - f2 = (f2 - f1) - f2 = (1 - 1) - 1 = -1; f5 = f4 - f3 = -1 - 2 = -3; If this is not what you want, you may need to update your description to avoid ambiguous.

Comment: @tsh Took me a while, but I think I understand what you're getting at. Does my latest edit address that?

Comment: @Zgarb Not the best when it comes to distributions, but I've added in a list of possible values for n = 1 ... 6

Comment: I was going to edit in the distributions, but I don't believe your last case is correct. I don't think there is a way to reach 6 or -3. I decided to edit it in anyway since I wrote it on a scrap of paper, but of course feel free to change it if I am wrong.

Comment: If given _n_ we just output *f_n*, this voids the requirement that the sequence should remember previous values, doesn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, the requirement that the sequence "remembers" previous values is means that tsh's comment above would be an invalid way to construct the sequence. Because \$f_n\$ is constructed from previous terms, those terms cannot change partway through the construction of the sequence. For example, while constructing \$f_6\$, you'd have to first get the values for \$f_{1,\dots5}\$. Then, when constructing \$f_7\$, the values of \$f_{1,\dots5}\$ would be the same as when getting \$f_6\$, whether they were outputted or not.

Comment: Ah, I see, So, "remember" means that in the construction of a given f7, _every_ occurrence of f1 etc should have the _same_ value.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes exactly. If you have a better wording, I'd love to hear it, I'm not too happy with "remember"

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Here's a suggestion: _Each random realization of the sequence must use consistent values. For example, if [...]_

Comment: Also, when you say _is chosen at random_, you probably mean _is chosen at random independently of previous choices_? This prevents the code from randomly choosing a sign and using it for all terms, for example

Comment: @LuisMendo That wording is nice, thanks! And yes, each choice should be independent, I'll edit that it

Answer (score 5):

## [Minimise a bijection \$\mathbb{N}^n\to\mathbb{N}\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/214131/66833)

Comment: Seems very possible. You can iterate the cantor pairing function \$\pi(\pi(\pi(a,b),c)\ldots)\$

Comment: @Sisyphus, yes, but can you iterate it \$n\$ times within \$n\$ bytes?

Comment: Also, I like this scoring idea but I fear that the abstractness of the task will scare away potential golfers. Maybe it would be better to choose a simpler task that has n as a parameter.

Comment: @Zgarb While I do agree that, because it's much harder with the self-referential part, a simpler challenge would probably do better (votes/answers wise), but I've got no issue with this going unanswered, and I think as is, it'll draw much more impressive answers with a more discriminating choice of bijections.

Comment: Finally, you're missing the condition that every natural number must occur as an output.

Comment: Plus, because of the self-referential part, I think that this doesn't close the door on any future challenges that allow you to choose your own \$n\$, or take \$n\$ as a parameter, so I'm happy with this scoring criteria. Also, thanks for noticing that, edited in.

Comment: I don't really see the point of the n-is-length idea. It seems like you just have to write code that works for any n, then plug in n equal to the length of the code (accounting for the replacement). Only perhaps an ultra-golfy language might be able to do something like n=2 in 2 bytes rather than writing a general solution.

Comment: @xnor IMO, it adds an extra level of complexity/difficulty to the challenge, in that you have to modify the actual code as you modify code length. Also, I don't think the generic "take \$n\$ as a parameter" version is particularly interesting, whereas requiring answers to link \$n\$ and their code is

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Can you give an example of an interesting thing a program could do in linking its code length? I'm really not seeing it. The only extremely minor thing I could see is that if you have, say, a 76 byte program that works excepts it has a spot you need to put the number in, you need to put in 78 to account for the length of the code and number.

Answer (score 5):

## [Quickly! Group together!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/215883/66833)

Comment: This seems like fun! I have one concern, though. The first is that keeping track of all of the restrictions that have already been used seems like an unnecessary headache. Testing if a language has been used is fairly easy using the SE search (you might want to add in some premade links to make it easier for people to do) and I think that will help the variety enough. This seems like it would become a headache faster than it is worth, even if you did something like updating the challenge each day.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yeah, that's my main concern is keeping track of everything. Maybe adding a Stack Snippet to the challenge body that extracts previously used restrictions could alleviate that (similar to what we did with my OEIS answer chaining for used sequences)? I'm hesitant to remove the rule about not reusing restrictions, because it could just lead to the challenge continuing ad infinitum with a couple of basic, repeated restrictions

Comment: Trivial restrictions are so numerous that I don't believe this rule is doing anything relevant to end the challenge faster. I'd recommend dropping it and thinking about some other way to limit solutions if you really want that.

Comment: I agree with @FryAmTheEggman about the restrictions. Your rule that languages can't be used on different days should be enough to ensure that the challenge ends eventually.

Answer (score 5):

## [Is it a vampire number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218772/66833)

Comment: The old challenge certainly suffers from strict I/O, but I don't have a strong opinion as to whether it should be closed in favour of this one. If you do go ahead, I suggest clarifying that \$x\$ and \$y\$ must both have the same number of digits and only one of them may end with 0.

Comment: @Dingus "strict I/O" is a bit of an understatement. I have a Jelly answer to this and the old one. This is 10 bytes, the only one is 45 bytes, and the difference in length comes entirely from having to format the output to meet the rules, which no-one likes doing. Good spot on the restrictions on \$x\$ and \$y\$

Comment: I definitely see your point. I'm not opposed to the repost, in case I wasn't clear.

Comment: I vote for the repost

Answer (score 5):

*I decide to change the statement a little, so people who don't know the language can easily understand the challenge. (apparently there are many)*

---

*Background*:

- I'm thinking about scraping some BF programs on this site for the fastest-code (or approximation) version of the other challenge, and I figure out that I need to have this, and I post it here as a code-golf challenge since it's somewhat interesting (and also pretty easy).
- It's possible to force programs to check if there are any extra characters too; however it might make the problem harder (only allow printable ASCII? Some scraped data might have non-ASCII characters, so it isn't really practical. Any Unicode characters as input? Most esoteric languages can't handle that.)

---

### Does this BF program have a simple memory layout?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

Given a string consisting of only the characters `+-[]<>.,` check if:

- All pairs of `[]` are matching (balanced), and
- There's an equal number of `<` and `>` between every matching pair of `[]`.

*Background: the inputs that this program output true are exactly the valid inputs for the related challenge [BF memory layout optimizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218690/bf-memory-layout-optimizer).*

[Reference implementation in Python 3](https://tio.run/##ZZBBDoMgFETXegrKSmJsNN0ZYNlLEBZUsZpSIECb9PRWBdM2Xc68l8nPt68wGn2a514O4CnU1BfWmasT9xb44FBFL8aoNs98EN2NsJrn2WAc6EYwabCreZZNw9IRAhlcU9SPwlqp@6JGSyXVrvCoLDFa1tgCHUjdAifDw2lwFsrLpGgTovZHP4MUttFhVcNL0vxA/A2rFaYdJXWxAUSWNhfeSxfSDyDGlDJaVoxiXmIO0c7Xe5LDtn6e3w).

#### Example input/output

Output true:

```
,>>,
,<++[->>+<<]
+<><>+
,[.,]
>.<
```

Output false:

```
,[>,]
+[>>>->-[>->----<<<]>>]>.---.>+..+++.>>.<.>>---.<<<.+++.------.<-.>>+.
].[
```

Undefined behavior: (your program can do anything when given those as input)

```
((((()()()()()){}){}){}())
$\="=".hex.$/
\!$/'?))='%<\..>
```

Comment: can you please make the rules a list, some of us are bad at reading.

Comment: @Alexbries But there are only two of them...

Comment: I was worried for a bit this would delve into Rice's Theorem territory (the similar question "does this BF program have bounded memory consumption?" would). Seems plenty simple though.

Answer (score 5):

## [Liars and Guessers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220510/liars-and-guessers)

Comment: this looks like a _very_ good challenge. I'd go with JS for the language.

Comment: Be careful. If the minimax algorithm is not too hard, then people can just implement it and effectively block all the other answers.

Comment: Isn't JavaScript very good for sandboxing? The browser is the sandbox. / Besides, you can ask people to explain suspicious code, obviously...

Comment: @user202729 Re sandboxing I was less worried about safety than clever people inspecting the program's memory/whatever. But I guess I can just forbid it.

Comment: @user202729 Re minimax, I was worried that it might be too trivial to come up with a perfect solution. I'll look into it.

Comment: IMO, either Python or JS would be suitable to this question. You can chose any of them and it should work fine. As this question is asking about strategy of guessing instead of golfing in specified languages. People try to answer this question are not required to know very details of the language used.

Comment: To my understanding, guesser_score = sum(times_guessed for number in ([0..255] repeat 10 times) for each liar), lower is better. (10 times repeating is required since most submission would relay on some random behaviors.) liar_score is defined similar but higher is better. Use liar_score - guesser_score or liar_score / guesser_score (I would prefer the div one) to get score for some answer.

Comment: [Wrote a Python implementation](https://github.com/Artemis21/guessers-and-liars). It treats liars and guessers as separate submissions.

Answer (score 5):

## Dedekind, cut! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Objective

Given a [Dedekind cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) of a real number \$x\$ and a positive integer \$n\$, print the real number represented by the Dedekind cut up to \$n\$ precisions, rounded.

### Dedekind cut

A **Dedekind cut** representing a real number \$x\$ is a boolean-valued function on a dense set that gives a falsy value for rational numbers under \$x\$, and a truthy value otherwise. In this challenge, the dense set is \$\mathbb{Z}[0.1]\$, the rational numbers with terminating decimal expansion.

Note that Dedekind cuts can represent *arbitrary* real numbers. Irrational, nonconstructible, transcendental, or even uncomputable numbers.

### Rules

- Direction of rounding is implementation-defined.
- For the inputted Dedekind cut, it shall be a black-box function accepting the decimal expansion (which is a string with an implementation-defined format) of elements in \$\mathbb{Z}[0.1]\$.
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation. This also applies to the rational numbers the Dedekind cut accepts.
- Output format is flexible. Outputting leading or trailing whitespaces is permitted.
- For the output, all digits after the decimal point shall be considered significant in this regard. The amount of significant digits after the decimal point must be exactly \$n\$. Trailing zeros cannot be discarded.

### Examples

- For \$x = 0\$ and \$n = 2\$, output \$0.00\$.
- For \$x = ¼\$ and \$n = 1\$, output \$0.2\$ or \$0.3\$.
- For \$x = ½\$ and \$n = 3\$, output \$0.050\$.
- For \$x = \sqrt{2}\$ and \$n = 3\$, output \$1.414\$.
- For \$x = -\pi\$ and \$n = 3\$, output \$-3.142\$. Note the rounding.

### Ungolfed solution

#### Haskell

An implementation with exponential time complexity.

```
import Text.Printf

showDedekind :: (String -> Bool) -> Int -> String
showDedekind x n = go2 0 where
    go1 :: Int -> Int -> String
    go1 m i = let
        s1 = printf "%+0*d" m i
        (s2, s3) = splitAt (length s1 - m) s1
        in s2 ++ (if elem (last s2) "0123456789" then "" else "0") ++ '.' : s3
    go2 i = case (x (go1 (n + 1) (10 * i - 5)), x (go1 (n + 1) (10 * i + 5))) of
        (False, False) -> go2 (i + 1)
        (False, True) -> go1 n i
        (True, True) -> go2 (i - 1)
        _ -> error "This is not a Dedekind cut"
```

Comment: So to be precise, the input value `x` is actually given as a [black-box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/78410), right? For output format, I recommend to keep it simple. You can even omit it entirely so that we can assume a convenient format for each language in use (under default I/O rules). Should the solutions theoretically support arbitrarily large `x` (with both signs)?

Comment: 1. Your first and 3rd test cases with n=0 don't fit the specification ("positive integer n"). 2. What is the scoring criterion?

Answer (score 5):

## [Self-Replicating Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220611/self-replicating-numbers)

Comment: Nice challenge, but I feel it would be more interesting if it took two inputs, m and n, and outputted either the first m n-order numbers or the mth n-order number.

Comment: @user I do like that; my original concept for the challenge was similar (outputting the first n distinct orders). I think your concept is more interesting, but I do worry about the run time - I'll run some tests and see if there are enough reasonable test cases. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: For the formatting thing, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference -- replace `$` with `\$`.

Comment: Add "exactly" (appear [...] **exactly** \$n\$ times [...]) in the definition too, if that's what you mean.

Comment: +1 nice challenge! I have no idea of how to verify that there are no 1st-order self-replicating numbers after 9.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti Thanks! Think of it this way; since you're checking all multiples of a number up to their square, every number from 10 and up will have the multiple of itself and ten checked - any number times ten is guaranteed to have the original number as a substring. Numbers from 100 and up will have the multiple of itself and 100 checked, and so on.

Comment: Oh you are right! That's clever (or I am slow ahaha)

Comment: Allowing output of the infinite sequence of n-order numbers would be nice.

Comment: @Razetime I wanted to make it a little more challenging by requiring both inputs - would it make sense to allow outputting the infinite sequence of numbers that are either m or n order, or is that too complicated? I want there to be reasons to choose either output option, if I choose to add more, and I fear that the infinite series of n-order will be the easier choice for a majority of languages. Let me know if I'm just overthinking it, and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman many recent sequence challenges allow output in 3 main ways: nth number, first n numbers or an infinite sequence. It is up to you to choose what you think suits the challenge best.

Comment: @Razetime Ohhh okay; I looked at a few other sequence challenges and pulled together a few options - I do think it rounded out the challenge a bit more, but now I'm not sure how better to format the test cases area to accommodate those additional output modes

Comment: Minor things: can you change the wording and formatting of the "The CHallenge" section to make it more obvious that you need to do one of the things (see some existing [tag:sequence] questions for more info)? Also can you clarify that you mean a substring *in decimal*? Can you clarify that "if the input is not valid" means "if no such number exists". Finally, what tags are you planning to use? [tag:code-golf] [tag:sequence] [tag:number] ...?

Comment: @pxeger Thanks, I have implemented all of your suggestions - let me know if you still feel any of those areas are lacking!

Answer (score 5):

## KoTH: Hunter-Gatherer Society

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

In this challenge, the goal is to write a bot (Javascript function) which survives for as long as possible with its tribe. The bots are placed on an island, with the ability to hunt, gather, farm, and build. Tribes can fight, and the last alive wins.

This challenge is complicated, and it's designed to be that way. I'd recommend starting out with bots that specialize in a particular type of strategy, like gathering berries or fighting. To keep this post from being longer than it already is, technical details will be included in the links labeled `More` at the end of each section. (**Meta:** These links don't go anywhere yet)

### Overview

Bots have hit points and hunger. In order to survive, bots need to eat. There are various foods, such as berries from berry bushes, bread from farming, and meat from hunting. Materials like sticks, rocks, logs, and ores can be found around the island, and used to make tools and buildings.

The island has grasslands, forests, and rivers. Rabbits and elk can be hunted for meat and hide, with sticks, rocks, or spears. Meat can be cooked over a campfire. Tribes can build walls to protect their farms and bases, and fight to defend them with weapons and armor. Bots can talk to their tribe members, and trade for rare materials.

### Hit Points, Hunger, and Turns

All bots have a number of hit points, and a number of hunger points. Bots start with 7.5 hit points, out of a maximum of 10. When they reach 0 or below, they die. Various actions take hunger. Bots start with 75, out of a maximum of 100, and when they drop below 0 hunger points they instead lose 10% of the hunger taken in hit points.

Games consist of a number of turns. During each turn, all bots can perform actions including moving, eating, harvesting, and fighting. Each action takes a certain amount of hunger, and every action performed in the same turn after the first one doubles the hunger taken.

**More:** Turns

### Terrain

The world consists of a square grid, with a radius determined by `floor(25 * sqrt(bot_count)) + 25`. The center of the grid will always be `[0, 0]`, with coordinated ranging from `[-radius, -radius]` to `[radius, radius]`. Positions will always be specified in absolute coordinates as an array `[x, y]`, and most actions that take a `position` argument will require the bot to be adjacent to that position unless otherwise specified.

This land is divided into four biomes:

- Grassland
- Forest
- River
- Ocean

The outer ring of 25 grid squares will be ocean. This consists of a beach closer to the center, with water continuing to the boundary of the world. Rivers will generate similarly, usually with a width of 5-10, with a thin beach on each side.

Each naturally generated terrain square can be one of the following:

- Plain
- Bush
- Berry bush
- Tree
- Stone
- Copper ore
- Iron ore
- Sand
- Water

Grasslands are mostly plain, with some stones and bushes. Forests are more interesting, with many trees and some stones, bushes, and berry bushes.

**More:** Terrain

### Movement

Bots can move in any of four directions: `north()`, `east()`, `south()`, or `west()`. Only some terrain can be walked into:

- Plain
- Sand
- Farmland
- Bush (+1)
- Berry bush (+1)
- Water (+2)

It typically takes 1 hunger to move. However, moving into certain terrain (marked with `+1` or `+2`) can take extra hunger. An addition hunger point is taken for every 10 items the bot is holding, rounded down. Multiple bots can occupy the same position.

### Food

There are four foods, which restore different amounts of hunger:

- Berries:      10
- Meat:         15
- Bread:        25
- Cooked meat:  40

Foods also restore 10% of their hunger restoration in hit points.

Berries can be collected from berry bushes, by returning `harvest()` when adjacent to (or standing in) a berry bush. Meat is obtained by hunting, bread is crafted with grain, and cooked meat requires a campfire.

Grain can be initially collected by returning `harvest()` when adjacent to (or standing in) plain land. It can also be collected from farming. Bread can be crafted by returning `craft(Item.BREAD)` while holding 1 grain and 1 rock. The rock will not be consumed.

**More:** Food, Harvesting

### Resources

Many types of terrain can be broken by returning `break(position)`, turning into plain land and giving items:

- Bush:         Stick × 1
- Berry bush:   Berries × 1
- Tree:         Log × 2
- Stone:        Stone × 1
- Copper ore:   Copper ore × 1
- Iron ore:     Iron ore × 1

Trees require an axe to break. All four will reappear after a number of turns if the land remains plain.

A stone axe can be crafted from 1 stick and 1 stone by returning `craft(Item.STONE_AXE)`, and will break after 10 uses.

**More:** Breaking, Crafting

### Farming

A stone shovel can be crafted from 1 stick and 1 stone by returning `craft(Item.STONE_SHOVEL)`. A shovel can be used to turn plain land into farmland, and will break after 20 uses. This is done by returning `shovel(position)`.

Grain can be planted on farmland by returning `plant(position)`. It will take around 100 to 200 turns to grow, although the amount of time is much shorter within 20 squares of water. Grain starts as `Growth.NOT_GROWN`, and cannot be harvested (only broken). It then becomes `Growth.GROWING` after about 70% of the total time, and will give one grain when broken or harvested. Finally, the last stage is `Growth.GROWN`, where two to four wheat are given from harvesting.

**More:** Farming

### Hunting

A stone spear can be crafted from 1 stick and 1 stone by returning `craft(Item.STONE_SPEAR)`. A spear can be used to hunt, as well as a stick or stone. Bots can attack at a position by returning `attack(position)` (`hunt(position)` and `fight(position)` are aliases). Movement happens before attacking, so simply attacking an animal's current position may not work. If attacking would hit multiple targets, damage is distributed between them evenly.

Sticks and stones have a range of 1, with sticks dealing 0.35 hit points, and stones dealing 0.75. Spears deal one hit point, with a maximum range of 2. A spear breaks after 10 successful hits. Attacking takes 10 hunger, whether or not any target is successfully hit.

There are two types of animals: rabbits and elk. Rabbits have 1 hit point, and elk have 4. Rabbits will move every 1 to 2 turns, avoiding bots if they are very close. Elk will move every 2 to 4 turns, and will always move away from attackers for 2 to 4 turns after being attacked. Rabbits will give the last bot to hit them 1 meat, and have a 25% chance of giving 1 hide to the second to last player to hit them. Elk are similar, giving 1 meat and 1 hide to the last bot to hit them, and 1 meat to the bot that hit them the 2nd to last time.

**More:** Hunting

### Tribes

All bots will be part of a tribe. Tribes are determined by the creator of the bot, can contain any number of bots from any number of writers. Bots in the same tribe will be able to recognize each other, while bots outside their tribe will only have their tribe name known. Tribe members cannot attack each other.

If a tribe member is next to another one, they can give an item with `give(name, item)`, or transfer any JSON-serializable data with `talk(name, data)`.

Armor can be crafted from 2 hide with `craft(Item.ARMOR)`. When a bot is holding armor, it can take up to 10 hit points before breaking. Bots fight with other bots in the same way they hunt animals. When a bot is killed, its items are distributed among the bots that attacked it recently according to the damage done.

**More:** Tribes, Fighting

### Building

Bots can build walls and campfires, by returning `build(build, position)`, where `build` is one of `Terrain.WOOD_WALL`, `Terrain.STONE_WALL`, `Terrain.CRATE`, or `Terrain.CAMPFIRE`. Wood walls require 2 logs, and take 10 hits with an axe to break, giving the bot that breaks it one log. Stone walls require 4 stones, and take 75 hits with an axe to break, giving the bot that breaks it one stone.

Crates require 1 log and 1 bronze, and can store items. If you're adjacent to a crate, you can store items in it with `store(position, items)`, and take an item with `take(position, items)`. Crates can store up to 40 items. The contents of crates are visible to any bot.

Campfires require 1 stone, and 2 sticks, and can be used to cook meat. Campfires can be given fuel using `fuel(position, item)`, accepting sticks, logs, and charcoal. Bots can cook meat or logs (which turn into cooked meat and charcoal, respectively) using `cook(Item.MEAT)` or `cook(Item.LOG)`, if adjacent to a campfire. Cooking meat uses 3 fuel, and cooking logs uses 5. A stick provides 1 fuel, a log provides 5, and charcoal provides 15.

A campfire can be broken with an axe, and will give the bot that breaks it all of the unused fuel it holds. Partially consumed logs or charcoal will not be given.

**More:** Building, Cooking

### Upgrading

Copper ore and iron ore can be cooked into bronze and iron in a campfire, requiring 10 and 15 fuel respectively. Bronze and iron can be used to craft stronger axes, shovels, and spears, by replacing the stone in the recipe with the corresponding item.

For axes and shovels, the material affects the durability:

- Stone axe:    10
- Bronze axe:   15
- Iron axe:     25

All shovels have twice the durability of a similarly strong axe. Spears are different, with all tiers having 10 durability. Instead, the number of hit points dealt is upgraded:

- Stone spear:  1.0
- Bronze spear: 1.5
- Iron spear:   2.5

Because these items are so rare, trading might be a good way for a tribe to advance. By returning `offer(sell, buy)`, any bot can offer a number of items they have (`sell`) for a number of items they want to have (`buy`). All bots will receive an array of offers made on the last turn, and can accept one with `accept(offer)`, where `offer` is an offer ID.

The `sell` array should contain IDs of items the bot is holding, while `buy` should be an array of objects. All objects should have an `item` property with the `Item` wanted, and an optional `durability` property can specify a minimum durability acceptable. If no minimum durability is included, only undamaged items will be accepted.

**More:** Trading

### Bots

Many arguments and functions involve enums including `Terrain` and `Item`. Here is a reference:

- `Terrain`: `PLAIN`, `BUSH`, `TREE`, `STONE`, `COPPER_ORE`, `IRON_ORE`, `FARMLAND`, `SAND`, `WATER`, `WOOD_WALL`, `STONE_WALL`, `CAMPFIRE`
- `Item`: `STICK`, `BERRIES`, `LOG`, `STONE`, `COPPER_ORE`, `IRON_ORE`, `CHARCOAL`, `BRONZE`, `IRON`, `MEAT`, `COOKED_MEAT`, `GRAIN`, `BREAD`, `HIDE`, `ARMOR`, `STONE_AXE`, `BRONZE_AXE`, `IRON_AXE`, `STONE_SHOVEL`, `BRONZE_SHOVEL`, `IRON_SHOVEL`, `STONE_SPEAR`, `BRONZE_SPEAR`, `IRON_SPEAR`
- `Growth`: `EMPTY`, `NOT_GROWN`, `GROWING`, `GROWN`
- `Animal`: `RABBIT`, `ELK`

All bots should be Javascript functions, which take four arguments:

- `grid`: A 15 by 15 grid centered around the bot, with all items being objects:

  - `terrain`: A type of `Terrain`
  - `details`: An object, with a `has_berries` property for `Terrain.BUSH`, a `growth` property for farmland (`Growth.EMPTY` if no grain is planted), a `hit_points` property for walls (starts as `10` for wood or `75` for stone), and a `fuels` property for campfires (array of `Items.STICK`, `Items.LOG`, and `Items.CHARCOAL`, does not include partially burned)
  - `bots`: An array of bots, with all being objects:

    - `tribe`: A string containing a tribe name
    - `name`: A string containing a bot name, if the bot is in the same tribe
  - `animals`: An array of animals, with all being one of `Animal.RABBIT` or `Animal.ELK`
- `bot`: An object with information about the bot:

  - `hit_points`: Hit points
  - `hunger`: Hunger
  - `position`: Position as `[x, y]`
  - `items`: An array of items held, with all items being objects:

    - `id`: A unique ID for this item
    - `item`: A type of `Item`
    - `durability`: For armor, axes, shovels, or spears, the remaining uses (or hit points) until broken
- `offers`: An array of offers from other bots on the last turn:

  - `id`: An ID unique to the offer
  - `sell`: An array of the items the seller is offering:

    - `item`: A type of `Item`
    - `durability`: For armor, axes, shovels, or spears, the remaining uses (or hit points) until broken
  - `buy`: An array of items the seller wants:

    - `item`: A type of `Item`
    - `durability`: For armor, axes, shovels, or spears, the minimum durability acceptable
- `talking`: An array of data sent from other bots on the last turn:

  - `name`: The name of the sending bot
  - `data`: The data sent by the bot
- `storage`: An object that can be used for storage between turns

## Meta

(Note that none of the links to `More` work yet)

- Is this clear enough as it is, without the technical details?
- Is there too much information, or is it too hard to read?
- Do you think there will be strategy and clever bot design?
- Would you compete in this challenge? Why not?

### New features

Things I recently added:

- Trading between tribes
- Communication within tribes
- Bronze and iron, and better tools
- Crates to store items

Comment: When you say "Bots start with 75, out of a maximum of 100, and when they drop below 0 hunger points they instead lose 10% of the hunger taken in hit points." Did you mean: "Bots start with 75 hitpoints, out of a maximum of 100, and when they drop below 0 hit points they instead lose 10% of the hunger taken in hit points."?

Comment: @DanielOnMSE The reverse, mostly. Bots start with 7.5/10 hit points, and 75/100 hunger. When a bot drops below 0 hunger, additional hunger is taken from the bot's hit points instead (but scaled by 10%)

Comment: Ahh okay. I think this contradicts "Bots start with 7.5 hunger, out of a maximum of 10. When they reach 0 or below, they die"
Unless hitpoints/hungers still mean something when dead?
Nice idea btw. I've upvoted. I'll continue to trawl through it and see if I can find any errors. I think I get what you are trying to say with the hitpoints/hunger but I think you may have accidentally swapped the two in some places?

Comment: @DanielOnMSE Ah, I see what you mean. I'll fix that.

Comment: Just food for thought. Might make the challenge more approachable if you wrote a script that created the world state and takes input/gives output every turn to the bots? Or is part of this challenge making the "game" itself? Perhaps you've already considered this and made something. Whether or not this is implemented will determine the complexity of this, imo. Like if you could create something everyone involved could use to test their bot? Also give it fixed input and output formats?

Comment: @DanielOnMSE Usually that's part of making a KoTH, yeah. There's a controller program (usually written by the author before posting) that manages all of the bots, sets up the games, determines the winner, etc.

Comment: This challenge seems very interesting but even more complex to me... but I'd give it a try. However, it would need many participating bots to utilize all of its features and make it fun to play. Technical note: `break` won't work as a function name (it's reserved) unless it's an object property.

Comment: @FZs Part of my goal when designing this KotH was specifically for it to be very complex; I'm hoping bots will be sort of forced to specialize. Thanks for noticing the `break` thing, I guess I'll rename that to `destroy` or `mine`

Answer (score 5):

## [Minimally destroy CGCC in Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221091/minimally-destroy-cgcc-in-game-of-life)

Comment: Just to clarify, you get an integer \$n\$ as input and must kill all but \$n\$ cells from the initial state to produce the shortest lived automata?

Comment: Are there performance requirements? This problem is in EXPTIME.

Comment: @Beefster No time requirements. And no, you decide how many cells you want to make alive (call that \$n\$) and which cells they are. You then run the game with those cells and the initial `CGCC` being alive until it reaches a point where all cells on the board are dead. Lowest \$n\$ wins.

Comment: Oh, I get it. You're supposed to add live cells around the initial CGCC so that the board eventually anihillates. The way you framed the challenge is a little confusing. You make it seem like you're supposed to remove cells from the initial configuration.

Comment: @Beefster I've edited the wording slightly, does it make more sense?

Comment: The wording is clearer now, but the issue is that "However, if we change the initial state to the following, by changing 13 cells, then, after 31 iterations, the board is empty" is sort of misleading because it prepares the reader to *remove* cells when you then say "And this is your task." I think it would be less confusing if you gave an example where adding cells to an initial state causes the pattern to eventually annihilate.

Comment: @Beefster The issue with that is that I don't actually have an example that fits the current rules :/

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create an example that fits the rules. You could instead give an example of a simpler pattern that, when a few additional cells are made live, leads to eventual annihilation. So the overall flow of the challenge description would be something like this: simple pattern, simple pattern + live cells --> annihilation, CGCC pattern creates still life + oscillators, description of the task and scoring.

Answer (score 5):

## [Decode Polybus Square/Tap Code/Prison Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222461/66833)

Comment: Nice challenge :) You need to add a scoring criterion (code-golf most likely), and you should provide a few input->output examples to help checking answers

Comment: Suggested testcases: `23 15 31 31 34` => `HELLO`, `24 25 31 32` => `IJLM`, `11 22 33 44 55` => `AGNTZ`. Add tags code-golf, decode and string.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted

Answer (score 5):

## Two Diehards Make a Glider

[game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

---

[POSTED](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221421/45613)

Comment: Is the WIP for the title or the challenge? The challenge looks mostly ok, but I'd be worried about having many solutions with the form: as simple as possible for the gliders with a well-known diehard placed far away. For the title, something like "gliders as emergent properties" or something could also be catchy.

Answer (score 5):

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221420)

Comment: Instead of saying that "Output is undefined if n<1, or if A is shorter than n" just specify that this won't be the case.

Answer (score 5):

## [I'm Jelly of Python (Cops)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222477/66833)

## [I'm Jelly of Python (Robbers)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222478/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## Plz Halp I Need $$$ Again

Bob’s startup is running out of money and desperately needs investors to keep it afloat. Although you have [helped Bob find the maximum number of investors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224515/plz-halp-need-investors-asap), Bob has quickly realized that more investors does not lead to more funds because different investors give different amounts of money. Each investor interested in Bob’s company wishes to schedule a meeting with a certain start and end time, and promises to invest a certain amount of money. However, some of the meetings times may conflict. What is the maximum amount of money he can get from his investors?

### Input Format

Input is given as an array of tuples of integers (or the equivalent in your chosen language). Each tuple `p` represents one investor, where `p[0]` is the start time of the investor’s meeting, `p[1]` is the end time, and `p[2]` is the amount of money promised.

For example, in the test case `[(0, 10, 30), (10, 20, 50)]`, there are two investors: one who wants to meet from time 0 to time 10 and offers $30, and one who wants to meet from time 10 to time 20 and offers $50.

Meetings will always have a positive duration, meeting times are always non-negative, and a meeting that ends at time `k` does not conflict with a meeting that starts at time `k`. You may assume that the input is nonempty, and you may use any reasonable I/O method for input.

Within reason, you may also take input in different formats (for example, as three lists, one which contains the start times, one with the end times, and one with the money offered).

### Output

Your program should output an integer, the maximum quantity of money that Bob can make.

### Test Cases

```
[(1, 100, 10), (1, 5, 3), (5, 10, 3), (10, 15, 3)] => 10
[(0, 30, 40), (20, 45, 30)] => 40
[(10, 40, 40), (60, 85, 60)] => 100
[(65, 100, 70), (10, 45, 80)] => 150
[(10, 15, 50), (50, 85, 10), (95, 110, 60)] => 120
[(100, 135, 80), (50, 70, 80), (80, 110, 30), (95, 100, 40)] => 200
[(65, 95, 70), (50, 75, 30), (35, 60, 80), (85, 115, 100)] => 180
[(30, 35, 80), (35, 65, 10), (75, 110, 40), (40, 45, 20)] => 140
[(80, 110, 50), (0, 5, 30), (95, 125, 50), (80, 85, 70)] => 150
[(25, 40, 10), (100, 115, 60), (15, 50, 90), (60, 95, 50)] => 200
[(100, 125, 50), (75, 80, 100), (30, 60, 20), (50, 65, 90)] => 240
[(15, 35, 80), (55, 70, 40), (30, 65, 90), (30, 55, 60)] => 120
[(15, 40, 50), (60, 95, 30), (35, 40, 70), (55, 60, 90)] => 190
[(40, 65, 80), (40, 75, 10), (5, 15, 80), (100, 115, 80), (15, 35, 100), (60, 95, 40)] => 340
[(5, 30, 60), (85, 105, 90), (35, 65, 80), (90, 115, 40), (85, 90, 80), (30, 60, 90)] => 270
[(55, 65, 30), (5, 15, 90), (50, 85, 100), (0, 15, 90), (65, 70, 70), (60, 70, 80), (35, 55, 20), (80, 105, 80)] => 290
[(0, 10, 90), (70, 85, 80), (45, 55, 20), (90, 105, 90), (55, 90, 50), (0, 25, 20), (85, 105, 30), (85, 90, 100)] => 380
[(10, 45, 40), (85, 115, 80), (85, 105, 30), (30, 50, 50), (20, 40, 80), (100, 115, 60), (100, 135, 70), (30, 35, 70), (35, 50, 30)] => 180
[(80, 105, 70), (60, 65, 50), (95, 105, 80), (55, 65, 100), (40, 75, 80), (95, 110, 70), (60, 70, 90), (65, 70, 50), (55, 85, 100)] => 230
[(80, 85, 70), (35, 40, 60), (60, 80, 80), (5, 20, 100), (30, 60, 100), (45, 50, 60), (45, 80, 60), (10, 20, 50), (50, 65, 60), (60, 85, 70)] => 370
[(50, 75, 100), (90, 115, 20), (50, 65, 10), (35, 50, 30), (90, 120, 90), (65, 90, 30), (20, 55, 40), (50, 75, 50), (75, 105, 10), (15, 35, 70)] => 290
```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are prohibited.
- Though not required, polynomial-time solutions are encouraged so that Bob does not have to wait forever for the result.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in each language wins.

### Meta

- Are there any errors with the computer-generated test cases? I've manually verified some of them but I may have overlooked something.
- Is there any ambiguity in the problem statement?
- Are there any other issues?

Comment: Test cases seems be ordered by end times. I'd suggest mixing them up (so no answer accidentally uses the order) or specifying the order. Also, in the example in the input format, it's `(10, 20, 50)` but you say they want to meet `5 - 10`. (And I prefer the `Output` section before the test cases, so people know what they need to do earlier.)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the challenge accordingly

Comment: Is it possible to take input as three lists, for start times, end times, and prices?

Comment: Sure - should I add test cases in that format?

Comment: You don't need to add testcases in different formats, simply state in your post that different formats are acceptable (and perhaps mention some different formats like the \$3\$ lists @rak1507 mentions).

Comment: [Link to the deleted main post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224593/plz-halp-i-need-again), so that it's easy to find and edit when this challenge is good to go :)

Answer (score 5):

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225601/compute-the-uncomputable-sort-of)

Comment: I think I saw l4m2's proposal which is essentially the same thing, but this one is arguably much better and clearly worded. Btw, the first example is just a special case of Chaitin's constant with power-of-0.5 weights.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible, if \$f(n)\$ is computable, isn't the limit of \$f(n)\$ computable by the definition of limit?

Comment: @CommandMaster Actually no! This is just one of a million ways in which limits can be counter intuitive.  For an example, imagine an \$f\$ where \$f(n)\$ just takes the first \$n\$ Turing machines and runs them for \$n\$ steps, if machine \$m\$ halts in the test run then you add \$2^{-m}\$ to a total (think about what this means in binary).  This is obviously computable, we can simulate Turing machines for \$n\$ steps and add rational numbers.  But the limit encodes the exact solution to the halting problem.  This is actually the first example number there.

Comment: Does \$f(n)\$ have to be an exact rational (i.e. a pair (numerator, denominator)), or can it be represented as a floating point number? In other words, can we output \$f(n)\$ as a floating point number which will, necessarily, be inexact for large values of \$n\$, as long as the algorithm theoretically works if given arbitrary precision?

Comment: @Delfad0r I'm not entitled to answer your question, but I don't think `float` or `double` are applicable here. Arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers are certainly applicable tho.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks for the clarification! Does the first option include, say, a pair `[numerator,denominator]` (even though it's not a built-in rational type)? In this case, is the pair required to be reduced (i.e. gcd=1)?

Comment: @Delfad0r I will add that as another form, and the second format shows a non-reduced fraction as an example so it would be all right for this format as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Drop some boxes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230079/drop-some-boxes)

Comment: Assuming you live in a world with gravity

Answer (score 5):

## Ouput Input... Forever

### Problem

Given input chars, output them repeatedly forever.

### Examples

```
abc       -> abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc...
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3]...
lo        -> lololololololololololololol...
```

**Dedication:** This is for all the tarpits out there!

### Questions

- Should a delimiter be allowed?
- I was imagining that the input would be cycled through infinitely in order, like in the examples. Should we enforce that as a rule, though?

  - Or should the rules just be: **Each char of input should eventually occur infinitely many times in output.** (Informally stated, but can easily be made mathematically precise.)
- Other thoughts!

Comment: If you go with "Each char of input should eventually occur infinitely many times in output", then you'd need to specify that no other characters should be outputted because otherwise you could just output all bytes in order, or output random bytes infinitely

Comment: I think that vast majority of languages here will just use some version of `x = input(); while(true) {print(x);}`, so I doubt this will be especially interesting except for in a handful of languages

Comment: Are you going to post this? :)

Comment: Are you going to post this?  It's been a month....

Answer (score 5):

## Open or close?

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237424/open-or-close-the-parentheses).

Comment: The calculator would be more useful if `)` were followed by `)` assuming another unbalanced `(` remains. Example: `"1*(2+(3*4)" -> ?`

Comment: @aschepler Good thing the calculator dev thought this through more than I did, because that's exactly what it does. I'll update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create the shortest code snippet of the power functions 1 through 10 which can be compiled to assembly code and which contains the minimum number of `imul` assembly operations. For better comparison use https://godbolt.org/ and either GCC or LLVM.

### Introduction

Did you know the fastest way to calculate x⁴ is not `x*x*x*x`, but `y = x*x; y*y` which saves one multiplication and is therefore faster. In mathematics and computer science this is called [addition-chain exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation).

The minimum number of multiplications for powers of 1 through 10 are

```
x^1  -> 0
x^2  -> 1
x^3  -> 2
x^4  -> 2
x^5  -> 3
x^6  -> 3
x^7  -> 4
x^8  -> 3
x^9  -> 4
x^10 -> 4
```

### Example

The assembly code looks as follows (C++ code below):

```
pow_1(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
pow_2(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_3(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_4(int):
        imul    edi, edi
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_5(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_6(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        ret
pow_7(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_8(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, eax
        ret
pow_9(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
pow_10(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        imul    eax, edi
        imul    eax, eax
        ret
```

One naive solution written in C/C++ and compiled with X86-64 gcc 11.2 and -O3 optimization on https://godbolt.org/ could be (Notice that I didn't need to optimize the code myself, but the compiler picked it up automatically. Aren't compilers awesome?):

```cpp
int pow_1(int num) {
    return num;
}

int pow_2(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int pow_3(int num) {
    return num * num * num;
}

int pow_4(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_5(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_6(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_7(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_8(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_9(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num;
}

int pow_10(int num) {
    return num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num;
}
```

Of course you can also use other language like Rust to create the same assembly code:

```rust
pub fn pow_9(num: i32) -> i32 {
    num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num * num
}
```

(Note Rust has an additional `mov`, but the challenge only focuses on the amount of `imul` assembly instructions.)

```
example::pow_9:
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     ecx, edi
        imul    ecx, edi
        imul    ecx, ecx
        imul    eax, ecx
        imul    eax, ecx
        ret
```

### Scoring

- The string must be compilable to assembly instruction with a compiler like GCC or LLVM (Note they have backends for many languages). You are not allowed to create the assembly instructions directly. Please also provide compiler version and flags.
- The whole string must be written in the same language (no writing C with another language)
- Out of bounds issues must not be considered, the code should work for integers 0 through 3.
- The generated assembly code can only contain the minimum number of `imul` needed for that power and `mov` and `ret` instructions
- The 10 functions in the assembly instructions should be named as I named them (order does not matter)
- Shortest string wins!

Good luck!

### Discussion

I've mistakenly posted this as a question to the meta site, but wanted this was my intended destination. After a few migrations the current location is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237367/create-the-shortest-fastest-implementations-of-powers-from-1-to-10). I've now reposted here trying to keep the style the same as I couldn't edit the post anymore.

Grain ghost has made two comments on how to improve the challenge:

- "Creating the assembly instructions not via a compiler is not allowed" and "The generated assembly must be similar to the provided assembly" strike me as not particularly clear, objective or enforceable
- Since we are dealing with assembly I would expect some discussion about precision and out of bounds issues

Thank you!

This is not a typical code golf challenge, but I'm very excited what kinds of meta programming techniques will show up.

Comment: @grain-ghost do I ping you this way? What I want to prohibit with the use of a compiler is that people simple create a program creating the assembly instruction string. The string must be compilable with GCC or LLVM. Similarity is hard, because compilers are weird (see my Rust example). May be say: The binary must contain the right number of imul instructions, at most two additional mov instruction and one ret instruction. Precision is no important with integer numbers as far I can think. Overflow is an issue, but I would simply neglect that case or restrict to numbers below or equal to 3.

Comment: If nobody's said it so far, welcome to Code Golf! This looks like a great challenge. For out of bounds issues, there's usually one of two approaches challenges will take, either having a minimum input size that must be supported, or just ignoring out of bounds issues within reason. Those would probably both work here, so it's entirely up to you. I agree with the two bullet points Grain Ghost brought up, those could probably use some clarification.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! :) I've updated the challenge. By restricting the amount of assembly instructions the submission must use `imul` (another feedback brought up to use for loops with addition) and guarantees similarity, because there is no other way to solve it. Another idea I had would be to only allow `mov`, `ret` and `imul` instructions.

Comment: Oh, so you're aiming to restrict what instructions can be used? That makes sense, I hadn't understood the wording right. You can definitely just choose a specific list of instructions to allow, which I'd recommend doing instead of the current requirements which are a little bit vague. There's actually a tag for that sort of thing, [tag:atomic-code-golf].

Comment: (Comment migrated from the [original question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24056/58563).) In addition to what was already pointed out on the main site, another potential issue with this challenge is that it's entirely possible to do it without any `imul`, for instance with inefficient addition loops.

Comment: I've updated the challenge accordingly I think limiting to imul (minimum number), mov and ret ensures similarity. I would like to encourage entries from many languages. Can I pick a winner per language?

Comment: We have a challenge on a similar topic [Shortest Addtion Chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123066/20260). This challenge looks different enough though.

Comment: I might not be the target audience as someone not into compiled languages, but the needing to go through a compiler strikes me as convoluted. What if we could just output the assembly, or some other representation of the sequence of operations? Needing to consider how a compiler would translate and optimize the operations seems finicky, but I guess maybe that's the whole point.

Comment: @xnor exactly the best solution will probably involve some kind of metaprogramming massaging the code so the compiler will optimize it. I've updated the challenge again with info about naming the functions. Can the challenge be posted now? :)

Comment: @JulianWgs It's your decision, but the general recommendation is to leave posts in the Sandbox at least 72 hours to gather feedback. I'd err on the side of waiting for this challenge because it might benefit from being seen by more people with knowledge in this specific domain and many people don't look at the Sandbox that often. I'd also suggest confirming with existing commenters that your edits have addressed their comments.

Answer (score 5):

## [Convert prefix to infix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237574/100664)

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4620/92901)?

Comment: @Dingus Yes, I'll just do prefix to infix instead :P

Answer (score 5):

### Minimum number of changed tiles to permit knight passage

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)

### Summary

Given a chess knight `K` that is *only allowed to step on permitted tiles `X`*, output **the minimum number of `.` tiles that must be changed** to an `X` tile in order to permit a passage to the destination `D`.

### Specification

- The chessboard is guaranteed to be *larger than 3x3.*
- The chessboard is guaranteed to have *one and only one* `D` and `K` in it.
- Sometimes, not using the existing `X` tiles can lead to a more minimal solution, so please take this in mind while solving this challenge. (e.g. the 2nd testcase)

### Test cases

```
..D.
XXXX
....
...K
```

Output = `1` (sequence = `(-2,+1), (+1,+2)`)

```
.D..
....
..XK
....
```

Output = `2`: (sequence = `(-2,+1), (-1,-2), (+2, +1), (-1, +2)`)

```
D.X
...
...
...
..K
```

Output = `1`: (sequence: `(-1, +2), (-1, +2)`)

```
DX.
...
...
...
..K
```

Output = `1`: (sequence: `(-1, +2), (-1, +2)`)

```
D.X.
....
.X.X
.K..
```

Output = `0`: (sequence: `(+2, +1), (-1, +2), (-1, -2), (-1, +2)`)

```
DXXX
XKXX
XXXX
XXXX
```

Output = `0`: (sequence: `(+1, -2), (+1, +2), (-2, +1), (-1, -2), (+2, +1), (-2, +1)`)

Comment: where is the ```D``` on the board and what is the ```W``` doing on the board

Comment: @DialFrost That's a typo. Fixed

Comment: i like this challenge otherwise!

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you! :)

Comment: May we assume that using existing `X` tiles leads to minimal solution or may there be "traps"?

Comment: May you give an example of not using the `X` tiles leading to the minimal solution?

Comment: I mean e.g. `DX./.../.../.../..K`, where putting `X` in the middle is sufficient and you don't need to reach the existing `X`.

Comment: @pajonk In this case, I think I'm trying to define a challenge that allows "traps" in the input. I'll clarify that in the challenge.

Comment: I've edited my example in the meantime to highlight its "trappy" nature. You may also want to add more test-cases (like with more Xs or where the ouput is 0).

Comment: @pajonk I've added your edited testcase and some of your testcase suggestions. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: your first test case is wrong, you can do it in 1: (-2,+1), (+1,+2)

Comment: @thejonymyster Fixed

Comment: suggested testcase: one where the straight path to the goal takes more X tile placements than following a longer route to the goal which already has many X tiles. Either way though, this is pretty much ready to post

Comment: May I assume the board is less than (or equals to) 8x8?

Answer (score 5):

## [Is it a fibonacci-like sequence?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242935/is-it-a-fibonacci-like-sequence)

Comment: input will be increasing... meaning first number>=next number?. Else i like the idea!

Comment: @DialFrost [I suggest you look in the dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/increasing)

Answer (score 5):

## [Gray code on N symbols](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243884/gray-code-on-n-symbols)

Answer (score 5):

## [Fibonacci triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243667/fibonacci-triangle)

Comment: this is more of a curve due to the incrementing length of numbers :P looks alright tho

Comment: @DialFrost Close enough, and I wasn't sure what else to call it :P

Comment: i think the test case for 20 is wrong, the first 1+1=2 and 1+2=3 dont align

Comment: @DialFrost Fixed, that's an error with my programming

Comment: suggestion for title qns: Fibonacci curve (cuz triangle has no application to this qns lol)

Comment: Is infinite output allowed, taking no input? (part of standard [tag:sequence] rules)

Comment: @pxeger Sure :P - no outputting the nth term though, as I feel that makes the challenge too easy.

Comment: @emanresuA Yes, I was thinking that as well. (although calculating the increasing string lengths might be complicated?)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pairs of integers ordered by their exponentiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243990/pairs-of-integers-ordered-by-their-exponentiation)

Answer (score 5):

## [Resolve references in a chat discussion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243973/resolve-references-in-a-chat-discussion)

Answer (score 5):

## Satisfy as many people as possible

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245549/106710).

Comment: im confused but nice challenge! :D

Comment: Wow, good challenge! They should use this for making servant robots; they'd make everyone as happy as possible :-)! The only part I didn't understand was the math formula; but, since I don't even know what the giant E means, that's not surprising. And as for title suggestions, something a little more catchy would be nice. Maybe something along the lines of "How many people can you satisfy?" (that's just a suggestion; I'm not very good at creative writing)

Answer (score 5):

## [Convert between graph representations.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245384/convert-between-graph-representations)

Comment: Awesome challenge! It seems ready to me and juding by the upvotes (might wanna wait 1 or 2 more days)

Comment: @DialFrost already posted ....

Answer (score 5):

## [Unshuffle my poker chips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246983/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## [Storing a band matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247139/16766)

Comment: Can you clarify in the definition that a band is symmetric (in terms of shape) about the main diagonal? Something like "the main diagonal and an equal number of adjacent diagonals on either side of it"

Comment: Wait never mind, somehow I missed the "in this challenge" further down

Answer (score 5):

## [Spend maximal money](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247454/spend-maximal-money)

Comment: For `10.00; [5,5,10]` is `[5,5]` an ok output? What should be the output for `10.00; [1,2,5,5,7]` (and why)? Suggestion: keep the challenge within positive integers.

Comment: @pajonk I prioritized choosing items from left to right.

Comment: You may want to alter the new examples to comply with your spec ("without equaling"). Also, does the order of the output matter (`[12.99, 0.99]` vs `[0.99, 12.99]`)? I also suggest explicitly stating that \$l\$ is an *ordered* list.

Comment: @pajonk YOU were the one how made me thought those were the correct answers, but ok.

Comment: and no, it will not be an ordered list. the output also doesn't matter.

Comment: If the input is not ordered, hot do we determine left-to-right?

Comment: aw damn you have a valid point lemme fix that

Comment: Your last example has an incorrect output. The answer should be `[2.00, 7.00]`

Comment: @jezza_99 fixed.

Comment: You say that you want to prioritize choosing items from left to right. For the examples you have given, this only results in an ordered output, which you've said is not important. The actual possible solutions do not change. I recommend either adding an example to test this criteria or dropping it. A suitable example would be `budget=10.00, prices=[1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 8.00]`. This should output `[1.00, 8.00]` even though `[2.00, 3.00, 4.00]` is also a potential solution

Comment: @jezza_99 i'm sorry but you've broken my brain. I'll just leave this here to rot

Comment: @BowlingPizzaBall what is the point of the rule "Prioritize choosing items from left to right"?

Comment: @jezza_99 Guess you could say there is no point. I'll remove that rule

Comment: @jezza_99 I thought this rule was to make the solution unique. Now (as in your example above) there may be multiple solutions.

Comment: @jezza_99, yeah, prioritizing left to right means there is only 1 valid solution.

Comment: @BowlingPizzaBall for your examples, there is only 1 valid solution anyway (as you have said the output order doesn't matter)

Comment: @BowlingPizzaBall your link doesn't appear to work, was the question deleted?

Comment: @jezza_99 yes. i did it myself.

Comment: Any reason? Seemed like the question was ok to publish

Comment: @jezza_99 lots of overreacting.

Answer (score 5):

## [BitCycle Metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247314/bitcycle-metagolf)

Comment: Since undefined behavior can have an effect on how small you can make a BitCycle program, I'd say you should either pick a specific implementation and say all answers must work on that implementation, or say that answers are allowed to work on any existing implementation.

Comment: @DLosc Okay, I will put in that it has to work on TIO.

Answer (score 5):

## Generate a Baudot punched tape segment

### What is Baudot?

From Wikipedia

> The Baudot code [boˈdo] is an early character encoding for telegraphy invented by Émile Baudot in the 1870s. It was the predecessor to the International Telegraph Alphabet No. 2 (ITA2), the most common teleprinter code in use until the advent of ASCII. Each character in the alphabet is represented by a series of five bits, sent over a communication channel such as a telegraph wire or a radio signal. The symbol rate measurement is known as baud, and is derived from the same name.

### Task:

For this challenge, your task is to write a program or a function that takes a string as its input and generates ASCII art that looks like a roll of punched tape. For the purposes of this challenge, you should specifically use the following variant, as it just happened to be the first image I found :P

[image: International Telegraph Alphabet 2 brightened]

---

For example where input is "HELLO WORLD\r\n" (note that carriage return is optional)

```
 *    *      
  **  * **  *
.............
*    *  *    
    *  *   * 
* ***  *  *  
hello worldcl
           rf
```

### Program Description:

- The program/function takes the input and turns it into a sequence of Baudot words (sequences of five bits)
- For each word, it makes a column of the first two bits, then a `.` then the remaining three bits

- Optional trailing space / newline

### Criteria:

- Output may not be output as an array unless there is no other valid option in the language. Trailing spaces and newlines allowed.
- Any acceptable input
- Assume all input characters are valid Baudot characters

Comment: No need to specify standard loopholes and I/O, they apply by default. You also override standard I/O with your third rule, so not much of a point to linking to it.

Comment: The Baudot code comes with the ability to switch between two modes (one for letters and one for figures). You'll have to clarify if we need to support that and how.

Answer (score 5):

## [Decipher a squashed sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249208)

Answer (score 5):

## All\$^{\dagger}\$ 3-character expressions

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

\$^{\dagger}\$*with some exceptions*

In your golfing language of choice, given no input, output all valid 3-character expressions in that language, with the conditions described below.

An **expression**, for the purposes of this challenge, is a string of characters that can be evaluated to some result. An example of an expression in many languages is `1+2`, which evaluates to `3`. If evaluation causes an error/exception/crash (e.g. `1/0` in Python), then it should *not* be printed.

Expressions can also have side effects (modify the state of the program), e.g. `y=2` in Ruby. These are allowed to be output but are not required. (In other words, you only need to print out [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) expressions.) Similarly, any expressions that rely on the evaluation of previous expressions, e.g. `a+2` (which requires that the value of `a` be set), are optional, unless they cause an error/crash, in which case they should not be output.

Some additional notes:

- White space and comments do not count as part of an expression - e.g. `2`   or `2#a` in Python are one-character expressions, so they shouldn't be printed.

Any language that does not have the concept of expressions, or has no expressions that are 3 characters long meeting the above requirements, cannot be used for this challenge.

As per usual code golf, the shortest program (in bytes) wins.

### Sandbox Questions

(This is my first challenge, so I don't really know what I'm doing, and feedback is greatly appreciated.)

I'm not sure how to deal with expressions that change the results of other expressions or change what counts as a valid expression, particularly in the case of side effects. For example, if in the language, evaluating any expressions causes an "answer" variable to be set, then all expressions have side effects and the challenge is moot.

I was considering having the condition for passing be "Your program satisfies the challenge if, after running, there are no other expressions you can evaluate.", but I'm unsure if that's a good requirement.

Comment: Nice challenge! However, bonus challenges are generally discouraged when writing challenges, so either remove the bonus, or make it another challenge.

Comment: ([See relevant meta post.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/92689))

Comment: Might it be possible to generate programs instead of expressions for languages that don't have expressions? Also I think, that you can use [tag:code-generation] tag.

Comment: @Jiří I think that is a meaningfully different request from generating all expressions -- it could probably be a separate challenge.

Comment: @thejonymyster It doesn't lead to any footnote -- it's just indicating that there are some exceptions to the word "all" (the same way that "with an asterisk" means "some exceptions apply"). It's probably unnecessarily confusing though -- I'll change it.

Comment: I'm still concerned about how exactly to define "having side effects" -- does anyone have a better idea of how to deal with that?

Comment: Does having side effects also include printing or reading input? Also I have found following [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28computer_science%29) which talks about expressions. Which led me to [Wikipedia page about Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) which had following sentence which might be the thing you are looking for: An expression is called referentially transparent if it can be replaced with its corresponding value (and vice-versa) without changing the program's behavior.

Comment: The thing is, some languages don't have something called an "expression", like golfing languages (and others). In that case, do we just output valid programs?

Comment: @Steffan I mentioned that in the description: "Any language that does not have the concept of expressions, or has no expressions that are 3 characters long meeting the above requirements, cannot be used for this challenge."

Comment: What is the definition of "expression" in regards of comments? Is it allowed to output strings that include comments? (e.g. `3#2` in python)

Comment: @Steffan Hm, I'd say that's a 1-character expression with a comment, so by the rules above it shouldn't be printed. But that's not a strong conviction on my part.

Comment: Also, is it allowed to print things with whitespace, e.g. `"   "` or `"  2"`?

Comment: Also, can random warnings be spouted to stderr?

Comment: @Steffan Thank you for asking these questions :)
I'd also say that white space isn't part of the expression, except in obvious cases - e.g. the expression representing the empty string `" "` -- so it shouldn't be allowed. 
For the second point: I think I'll say that expressions generating errors that don't stop execution of the program are allowed, so yes. Those expressions probably shouldn't be required to output though (?)

Comment: For the warnings, I can actually disable them with a flag (like `-W0` in ruby), so it's fine either way. So as far as spaces, `"  2"` isn't allowed, I guess. And  `- 2` isn't allowed either, I guess? Welp, this is going to add some bytes lol

Comment: @Steffan Yeah, the problem is programming languages deal with these things in many different ways, and I don't know how to account for them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137828/discussion-between-adam-and-steffan).

Answer (score 5):

## [Have you heard of tralindromes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250395/78410)

Answer (score 5):

## Radiation Hardening Koth [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening)

Comment: Why not the mean?

Comment: You could get really luckly sometimes and get paired against "almost dead" programs giving you a very high score with no real effort. Or get really unlucky and the first program in the first round guesses the single essential character in your source code. I think the median will compensate for this randomness and give a better idea of the general performance of a program.

Comment: Ah, okay then. Got it.

Comment: I would say multi-language koth's land up bad cuz (length) 100 is a little too much already for python but 100 is like a no-go for c++ (i guess)

Comment: The 255 byte limit is not intended for it to be a challenge to fit your code in that space, that's pretty doable in most any language. The idea is you can't stuff your code with a gigabytes of comments to simply reduce the chance of a important character being deleted.

Answer (score 5):

## [Divisor of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250942/108879)

Comment: May we assume the input string has positive length?

Comment: @pajonk yes, you can

Comment: You may also want to specify what to expect within the string (letters, whitespace, special characters?) - I suggest only lowercase letters.

Comment: Can the output have duplicates? Can it be in any order?

Answer (score 5):

## [The second even sublime number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251351/78410)

Comment: the thing is, the number is still short enough that in what I think is most languages, it's shortest to just print it

Comment: @Steffan At least `71547118063305763497095299547369280601<<126` is shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## [Re-Name all identifiers to a single letter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/re-name-all-identifiers-to-a-single-letter) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: @tsh Scoping rules are more like python. Variables are implicitly declared when they are first used.

Comment: For `(aa (ab ac ad) (ad ad))`, should I output `(a (b c d) (b b))` or `(a (b c d) (e e))`?

Comment: @tsh `(a (b c d) (b b))` since `ad` is defined in a scope that has closed.

Comment: I hoped the sentence "A variable is created when it first appears" would clarify this case

Comment: And then, should `(aa (ab ac ad) (ad ad) ad)` be `(a (b c d) (d d) d)` because `ad` is defined on the outer layer? If so, I would expect add these two as testcases.

Comment: Or maybe `(aa (ab ac ad) (ad ad) ad (ab ac ad) (ad ad))`?

Comment: @pxeger I explicitly state you are allowed to take input as a ragged list

Comment: I'm confused with the `kor` (2nd) and `be` test cases. Could you clarify rules which were used to produce those results?

Comment: @pajonk you are right the second `be` test case is incorrect. Fixed now

Comment: Suggested test case: `((x y) y)` - is it `((a b) a)`?

Answer (score 5):

## [Enumerate the rationals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253714)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: +1 for including negative rationals. There are many one-to-one mappings from Z+ to Q+, and some of them may be better suited for golf when extended to Q.

Comment: [Possible dupe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90232/output-the-nth-rational-number-according-to-the-stern-brocot-sequence)

Comment: Are we submitting a function that generates this mapping?

Comment: I'd recommend providing an example mapping.

Comment: Also, to answer @pigrammer : I think so, yeah. Also, I *think* since it's a [tag:sequence] question, there are some [standard ways you can implement the challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info). However, this might not apply here because we're not just generating a sequence, so not all of the output methods listed may apply.

Comment: @pigrammer The idea is with to go with [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) defaults, but (for function submissions) allow mappings from arbitrary contiguous subsets of \$\mathbb Z\$ rather than only \$[0,\infty)\$ or \$[1,\infty)\$. Let me know if you have any suggestions on how to make that more clear.

Comment: @emanresuA It is one way to solve this, but there exist multiple alternatives, some of which are almost certainly simpler than that.

Answer (score 5):

[Implement the flip-floperator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253206/implement-the-flip-floperator)

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:functional-programming]

Answer (score 5):

## [Traverse a rectangle's antidiagonals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254367/traverse-a-rectangles-antidiagonals)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first challenge!

Comment: Suggested title change: "Traverse a rectangle's antidiagonals"

Answer (score 5):

## Perceptron

*[There was a previous perceptron question but it was closed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171296/single-perceptron-implementation). Also it required a lot of extra stuff that's not normally part of the perception algorithm like I know it. This question will be much simpler*

The [Percepron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is a extremely basic classification algorithm. While it still has some limited use it's been mostly overtaken by gradient descent based algorithms that can match much more complex functions. Still its fun and easy to implement, and is the foundation for many more complex algorithms.

The dot product is defined as follows:

$$(A_0, A_1, \dots, A_n) \cdot (B_0, B_1, \ldots, B_n) = A_0 B_0 + A_1 B_1 + \ldots + A_n B_n$$

### Algorithm Description

Percepron can classify vectors into 2 categories, simply by taking the dot product with some vector. If this is positive, you are in category A, if negative, then not.

The algorithm to compute this vector works as follow:

```
set the initial vector to <0, 0, ..., 0>

while not every data point is classified correctly:
    let p be the first incorrectly classified point
    if the dot product is positive or zero but it should be negative:
        add p to the vector
    if the dot product is negative or zero but it should be positive:
        subtract p from the vector
```

Among the many weaknesses of this algorithm is that it runs forever if no solution exists, that it can only classify categories separated by a straight plane, and that that plane must pass through the origin.

You *do not* need to follow this exact algorithm as long as you can guarantee a correct vector in all the cases this algorithm would.

### The task

Take as input a list of positive tuples and a list of negative tuples. All tuples will all be the same length, and can contain any real number representable by a 32 bit float. Then output a vector that perfectly classifies them.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.

You may also take input as a single list of `((x0, ..., xn), category)` tuples. You may take the length of the tuples as a extra input if desired.

You may assume a solution exists for the input given.

The tuples in the input will *always* have 1 as their last value, representing bias.

### Test Cases

Note: Many of these can be bisected by many different hyperplanes, any of them would be a valid result. Your code may still be correct if it produces very different values from this.

```
[
    {
        "positive": [[1,0, 1]],
        "negative": [[0,1,1]],
        "result": [1,-1,0]
    },
    {
        "positive": [[12.12958530911699, 71.71547437602891, 17.615042787292396, 1.0], [22.894324259518754, 7.747740085241489, -16.379692578583914, 1.0], [-77.19508767650036, 26.391457800328325, -34.128081828012256, 1.0], [96.46713849700853, 8.223882871718914, 95.59810235088628, 1.0], [95.47166665625838, 36.07081574287895, 20.660512993212635, 1.0]],
        "negative": [[-41.92974660410673, -42.941790456679854, 21.407959882725905, 1.0], [-99.40397441836177, 26.174868779681844, 56.51788064358769, 1.0], [34.482060088467364, -96.36102804944655, 1.5810491199434153, 1.0], [-43.06995918058733, -65.8456447109237, -99.04122951157478, 1.0], [7.7462310407688335, -10.894130800401939, 77.86204331190197, 1.0], [44.47180923569721, -93.53543659179937, 6.715910740415197, 1.0], [71.16273132699712, -80.16856861976358, 48.05726245445331, 1.0]],
        "result": [78.64936114023355, 237.2180619264857, -42.5708443640236, 10.0]
    },
    {
        "positive": [[19.891204296811196, 10.95935510782877, 25.985095341720097, -39.87626202198886, 13.054847014298801, -0.8134570474536389, -54.24129976411458, 1], [-16.576268085926657, 4.5002152868197385, 6.698984554370156, -49.780067496976976, 3.9392362908185703, -11.457246915347255, -3.84485029930714, 1], [-6.424223219895211, -67.86203596702003, 0.6670934629448197, -67.56926034741468, -34.71326779844648, -19.40781793399796, -38.93217338522913, 1], [-55.06122442753092, -46.49216596542017, -28.522294222446035, -30.89448675440849, 25.85546157303159, -28.753484757197114, -67.37074950075419, 1], [12.753734640663126, -42.688681313433065, -37.073894323478854, -22.678023584770216, -12.23724620287598, 4.467063264393019, -28.749388172615724, 1], [-25.894264060028036, -4.384289071814308, 25.545930397049247, -53.005653882689884, -17.7501576060518, -19.66585588898353, -33.29502103119091, 1], [-32.104636572417846, -61.44888846917201, -41.89407929533455, 20.32097494020971, 8.703788581939762, 12.493571659393822, -35.255247777162495, 1], [24.15536843650885, -25.610207061176325, 16.08185788882571, -34.478497500787185, -18.915615320612233, 24.782283056323323, -24.770226555932894, 1], [6.765979248514711, -1.6248990886835486, 19.091220818794667, 14.715692506417057, 7.953257187955259, 12.722665623234263, 14.914783085366352, 1]],
        "negative": [[-2.7270414497182855, 8.676310678740919, -72.98709301742022, -7.70910010724549, 10.477333664984855, -17.506198964389014, 18.233248667960424, 1], [-43.3010158973477, -20.807005424922295, -77.5083019019948, 16.126838313178908, -40.490353240152864, -11.81562605632648, -8.902497984641357, 1], [-31.71159835398403, -14.73301578999785, 13.902967116929815, -21.834371921202447, -40.86878402777407, 6.742152812766307, -16.213431636063206, 1], [-66.57071699396832, -2.6930106603672783, 24.856421108284607, 26.02555433076685, -45.195502153813656, -60.583102046347044, 18.622821621702442, 1], [-47.07567023723187, 8.668277396085415, -55.64099369519978, -24.3651014072761, -77.50500543887348, -29.67008512028478, -27.6004244984169, 1], [16.02465948636585, -64.28947887797132, -18.663992818184852, 11.001922130635734, -65.96111461946506, -70.07973218635979, -41.525576739268594, 1], [-33.6451045267202, -8.496296235717935, -20.129571219612984, 9.152732883489037, 10.242775447179753, -61.865587395289765, -32.78507965995476, 1], [-59.32306321222039, 12.522731642519034, 22.026994802405454, -18.062615366497297, -8.713470639955815, -44.04186584475624, 27.84951438666559, 1], [15.30669132488326, 4.865567302204951, -2.782248675090557, 24.252984759612147, -31.883249650258065, 0.5697927616565579, 22.431436239098076, 1], [1.0357436812954433, -32.44164907799862, 13.942522314820707, 16.30751529733827, -12.905194523861582, -22.446463524560656, 12.651474924205772, 1], [-56.03563699153419, 12.024854226295957, -39.90028407341309, 26.9268535257967, 23.808505964904285, 0.34968582027003947, -29.362006601750707, 1], [-85.14402438073334, -15.501824729148709, -63.38128746811267, -42.15734961052637, -4.1615796887736565, -7.25189532732314, -27.223088213381402, 1], [2.7529807581849184, -23.668062096200217, -9.028343561579462, 2.5495275958544283, 15.88901518194605, -59.28742737700396, 25.402434735936126, 1], [-49.514159298902705, -24.01610873489301, 19.949647054069544, -41.1158129509881, -53.808681913915706, -11.175092994514387, 16.753648710377945, 1], [13.052884356788013, -29.298799492103925, -11.675938518634197, -11.229831992030299, -82.661335125941, 0.4488670991709114, 15.5168860373427, 1], [-10.923814330565236, -44.964063927868544, -38.9909686186201, 15.763631832856007, -44.00734436715622, -54.69686019599016, -52.81999206838163, 1], [-43.815947420234714, 19.90446963235277, 4.773988726751696, -47.12560089860667, 13.028054180292472, -39.81105100874389, 16.639915018971934, 1], [-60.88215048423795, 18.63815015768826, 27.157195120177462, -31.93335885907136, -6.562377024790365, 20.3179674395969, 9.210423673803817, 1], [-20.199358866077134, -50.594347683405196, -65.49273675929138, 19.37323156150201, -13.877303200574588, 19.536120330891066, -17.908737459942998, 1], [-11.03148069515855, 18.400073052625856, -65.34212863735566, -5.32988003172234, 0.7010084382675785, 26.36787095325562, 22.718825279142763, 1], [-30.028696420764177, -20.038640467728513, -47.66006964061526, 1.669739637216125, 3.3366149257696947, -20.495524621115493, 11.79886970131642, 1]],
        "result": [53.402165827630355, -96.34048665666451, 46.75018310196545, -58.648563298215464, 167.65173848467344, 54.84963473487821, -66.47771531555354, 6]
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you talking about "perceptron"?

Comment: Could you add a brief explanation of what a "dot product" is?

Comment: Your second link says "Percepron", I assume it should be "Perceptron". A small error, but worth fixing.

Answer (score 5):

### [Clutch Wordle Solver with known inputs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255493/clutch-wordle-solver-with-known-inputs)

Comment: A couple of test cases would be most helpful.

Comment: Added a use case and a table with the solution set. :D

Comment: Looks like a good idea, and draft, for a first challenge! My main suggestion would be this: we like to allow input/output to be as loose as makes sense, as it can often lead to creative solutions. So, I'd suggest rewording the i/o section to something along the lines of:

Comment: "Input: - A list of letters and indices (0 or 1 indexed, your choice), indicating the location of confirmed/green letters; - A list of letters and indices (consistently indexed), indicated yellow letters (i.e. the index is a known location the letter is not; - A list/string of letters that are yet to be guessed." /// "Output: All potential "words" of exactly 5 letters, such that the green letters are in the indicated indexes, the yellow letters are not in the indicated indexes, and the words consist of only the green, yellow, and remaining letters. The output may be in any order"

Comment: It's also worth including the "generic" catch-all for input/output, something along the lines of: "You may take input and output in any [convenient method or format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)" just to cover the "weird" programming languages that treat lists, strings, and numbers differently

Answer (score 5):

## [Salacious Bacon Tripod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257159/salacious-bacon-tripod)

Comment: So Bad Task (not saying it bad but this fits SBT)

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that acronyms at the beginning and end of the text won't be replaced (as aren't surrounded by spaces)?

Comment: @pajonk that was an unintended consequence of trying to make it so that words are "letters surrounded by a gap". I've fixed that now.

Comment: Another thing, will the acronym consist only of distinct letters?

Comment: @pajonk I've added that clarification to the challenge

Answer (score 5):

## [How many sorting networks?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261248/how-many-sorting-networks)

Comment: Well done there!

Answer (score 5):

## [Is it a valid chemical?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259143/91213) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Comment: What if it's only possible to construct multiple distinct molecules? e.g. `[1, 1, 1, 1]` (2H₂)

Comment: Suggested test case: `[0] => true` (to complement `[0, 0] => false`)

Comment: This challenge will help me pass  chemistry

Comment: Suggested test case: `[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]`, representing trioxidane. Though this molecule is too unstable, it's still truthy in this regard.

Comment: Also, this is just a minor nitpick, but ozone isn't shaped like a triangle.

Answer (score 5):

### Meccano construct a 17-gon

I recently read an interesting manuscript: [Gerard ’t Hooft, *Meccano Math I* (2006)](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/)

I will summarize the key bits here and then present a bit of a challenge.

Meccano bars are metal strips with holes in them at integer lengths. A bar of length \$n\$ has \$n+1\$ holes evenly spaced along it. Two bars may be attached at a two of their holes to form a joint.

[image: Simple joint with two bars]

A configuration is rigid when there is exactly one way to connect the given bars at the specified holes. For example all triangles are rigid:

[image: Rigid triangle]

However quadrilaterals are nearly universally non-rigid:

[image: Non-rigid quad]

As the joints share a degree of freedom. All configurations with a degree of freedom are not rigid, however not all zero degrees of freedom configurations are rigid. For example

**EXAMPLE HERE**

### Task

Your task is to produce a set of bars, along with their lengths and which holes are attached such that it forms a rigid construction, and 17 of the Meccano bars in your solution form the edges of a regular 17-gon.

### Scoring

Your score will be the number of Meccano bars used in your solution, with ties being broken by the sum of their lengths. Your goal is to minimize your score.

Comment: Your example of a 0 dof system that isn't rigid can be a flattened triangular prism with all strips of equal length. There is some theory behind this – cf. Laman graphs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/262647/117478)

Comment: You'll probably get a comment saying "please add a description in plain English".

Comment: @Bubbler oeis should have a good explanation

Comment: @Bubbler [tag:status-completed] (tag rendering isn't that good)

Comment: <s>Then you can denote \$T(T(T(\cdots T(n)\cdots )))\$ into \$T^n(n)\$.</s>

Comment: @tsh I forgot to link to the posted challenge…

Answer (score 5):

## [Compute the convolution of two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263716/compute-the-convolution-of-two-strings)

Comment: I don't think it's been done or that it's too easy. I probably wouldn't tag it [tag:polynomials]. It's enough to note the similarity in the problem description. It might be a good idea to have a test case with two non-empty inputs of non-equal lengths.

Answer (score 5):

## Output an inversely proportional sequence

Inspired by [Wheat Wizard's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268799/output-an-infinitely-proportional-sequence#comment583980_268799) on [my previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268799/100664). While that challenge requires having the ratio of consecutive integers grow arbitrarily large, this challengne requires the ratio growing arbitrarily small, a change that at first glance looks trivial but substantially changes the challenge. While most answers to the previous used a simple recursive formula, I haven't been able to find any simple closed-form formula for this.

In this challenge, an *inversely proportional sequence* is defined as a infinite sequence of positive integers such that:

- All positive integers are contained infinitely many times within the sequence.
- As more and more terms are added to the sequence, for all positive integers \$n\$, the ratio of the number of \$n+1\$s to the number of \$n\$s in the sequence must grow arbitrarily large.

I haven't been able to find a closed-form formula for such a sequence, but one possibility is the following (newlines added for clarity):

```
1,
1, 2, 2,
1, 2, 2, 2, [9 3s]
1, [4 2s], [16 3s], [64 4s]
...
```

Each line number \$n\$ contains \$1 \text{ 1}, n \text{ 2s}, n^2 \text{ 3s}\$ etc up to $n$. It's pretty easy to see why this satisfies the requirements: for example, the number of 1s in the first \$n\$ lines is \$n\$, and the number of 2s in the first \$n\$ lines is \$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1\$. The quotient of these is \$\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1}{n} = \frac{(n+1)}{2} - \frac{1}{n}\$, which clearly grows arbitrarily large as \$n\$ goes to infinity. A similar argument can be made for all other pairs.

An example of an invalid sequence is this:

```
1,
1, 2, 2
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, [8 4s]
```

Each line number \$n\$ contains \$1 \text{ 1}, 2 \text{ 2s}, 4 \text{ 3s} ... 2^n \text{ ns}\$. While this does contain every positive integer infinitely many times, and contains each positive integer less than the previous, it does not contain each integer infinitely less than the previous. In the limiting case, the sequence contains twice as many 2s as 1s, twice as many 3s as 2s, and so on.

Your challenge is to output any inversely proportional sequence. Standard [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply - you may output as a function that takes \$n\$ and outputs the \$n\$th or first \$n\$ terms, or output an infinite sequence in some form. You may use 0-indexing or 1-indexing.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Meta

- If you've found a closed-form (ish) formula for such a sequence I'd appreciate if you comment it.
- Is this sufficiently different from the previous challenge? 6 people seemed to think it was.

Comment: The number of prime divisors is such a sequence.

Comment: As is the sum of digits (in any base \$\geq2\$)

Answer (score 4):

## BlackJack Part II

Repost from the original sandbox

> As I had a blast working on the
>   original KOTH challenge, I wanted to
>   come up with another. For me, the fun
>   of these AI challenges is in refining
>   a comparatively simple bot which plays
>   a very simple game subtly. Due to the
>   probabilistic nature of card games, I
>   think that blackjack could be an
>   interesting KOTH game just like TPD.

## Rules

- Bots play at tables of four (4) competitors and one (1) dealer
- One (1) shoe is shared by all players **and the dealer** until it is exhausted, at which point a new randomly shuffled deck will be added and play will continue. The bots ARE NOT (at present) NOTIFIED of the addition of this new deck. [TODO? would make card-counting a LOT harder...]
- There is a buy-in of 10 per round, and cards are free
- There is no bet maximum as bets are between the player and the house, yet the bot must have sufficient chips to immediately finance the bet.
- Perfect/ideal hand has a score of 21
- All face cards have a value of 10
- All numeric cards are worth their number
- Aces are worth 11 or 1. this will be dealt with automatically by the framework, not the bots.
- Scores in excess of 21 which use an ace as 11 force the ace to reduce in value to 1
  scores in excess of 21 which cannot be coerced below the threshold of 21 "bust" the bot
- The dealer draws until he busts, or excedes a score of 17.
- The stake is subtracted from chips, so the chips value is the number of credits which are available to the bot for betting.

## Dealing and Bot Moves

1. When the game starts, each player is
   iteratively dealt one card, and has
   the $10 buy-in fee/minimum bet
   subtracted from their chips.
2. Then (in the same order as they were dealt to) each bot is executed as described in the "Programmer's Interface" section and **must** make a move or stand. Betting is considered a move. ***NOTE THAT BETTING DOES NOT AFFECT BOTS' ABILITY TO MAKE FURTHER MOVES.*** It is very possible to bet and then draw a card, and it is possible to draw multiple cards and them bet before standing.

## Programmer's Interface and Legal Moves

As documented in the CardShark class:

```
#   DOCUMENTATION
#       INPUT SPECIFICATION
#          $ ./foo.bar <hand-score> <hand> <visible cards> <stake> <chips>
#          <hand-score>     is the present integer value of the player's hand.
#          <hand>           is a space-free string of the characters [1-9],A,J,Q,K
#          <visible cards>  every dealt card on the table. when new shoes are brought
#                           into play, cards drawn therefrom are simply added to this list
#                           !!! THE LIST IS CLEARED AT THE END OF HANDS, NOT SHOES !!!
#          <stake>          the  number of chips which the bot has bet this hand
#          <chips>          the number of chips which the bot has
#       SAMPLE INPUT
#          $ ./foo.bar 21 KJA KQKJA3592A 25 145
#
#       OUTPUT SPECIFICATION
#          "H"|"S"|"D"|"B"  (no quotes in output)
#          "H"              HIT - deal a card
#          "S"              STAND - the dealer's turn
#          "D"              DOUBLEDOWN - double the bet, take one card. FIRST MOVE ONLY
#          "B 15"           BET - raises the bot's stakes by $15.
```

## Winner Selection

The winner would be the author of the bot which consistently accrued the most chips over a yet-to-be determined number of tables and rounds.

## Code Review [github](https://github.com/rdmckenzie/CodeGolf/tree/master/blackjack)

## Issues & ToDo

None! (no known problems at least)

<del>PS. How do I tag questions/answers?</del> thanks @dmckee
[ai-player]
[card-game]
[koth]

## Version History

5/25 - 0020 - v1 - updated code on GitHub which fixes a bug with the dealer. DD still scores monstrously for unknown reasons. tagged this post (with any luck).

5/25 - 0800 - v2 - bugfix on github which correctly implements DoubleDown, resulting in drastically reduced scores from the double-nut bot.

5/25 - 0920 - v3 - updated the test case to match the input specification. Added the rules for the dealer.

5/25 - 1100 - v4 - added a description of the table and shoe system.

5/25 - 1620 - v5 - added an explanation of the betting and card-dealing system, major status update.

5/27 - 1700 - v6 - ready to roll the contest...

Comment: Tags: [ai-player] and [card-game] seem naturals, though neither exists on the site as yet. What else?

Comment: The `SAMPLE INPUT` isn't consistent with the `INPUT SPECIFICATION` - do the args include the current score or not? How many decks of cards should we assume to be used? Does `<chips>` include `<stake>`? How does the AI dealer play? Is each bot-dealer pair using a separate shoe (so that when I stand the dealers cards are drawn fairly from all those not included in `<hand>` and `<visible-cards>`)? When does betting occur?

Comment: should players be notified of the number of decks in play, or not? The issue is that decks are dealt from until the deck is exhausted, then the "cannot pop from empty list" error signals the creation of a new shuffled deck then continues drawing as if nothing had happened. This means that multiple decks can be in play at once, but the statistical worst-case is that each player has three or four cards, which makes between fifteen and twenty samples split between two decks of 52. It shouldn't make a difference to score-based bots, but card-counters will need to detect or be notified of the chage

Answer (score 4):

Given a text, determine the language it is written in. The possible languages are: English, Danish, Romanian and Hungarian.  The shortest program wins.

Some examples of text in each language can be found at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org)

- English http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt
- Danish http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/12167/pg12167.txt
- Romanian http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11756/11756-0.txt
- Hungarian http://www.gutenberg.org/files/30163/30163-0.txt

You are required to include examples of runs on text files other than the ones provided here.

The input file name is given as a command line argument. Except the input text, you are not allowed read additional files (e.g. to train your program) so please encode any data in your program.

Your program must output on of the following words *English*, *Danish*, *Romanian*, *Hungarian*.

Examples

```
$ ./language pg2600.txt
English
$ ./langauge pg12167.txt
Danish
$ ./language 11756-0.txt
Romanian
$ ./language 30163-0.txt
Hungarian
```

Comment: Another source of plain text passages might be the Gutenburg project. They do have books in languages other than English.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the text problem to include some books from Gutenberg.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54760/ich-ne-know-pas)

Comment: Looks pretty trivial to me. Any sufficiently long text will have `ă` if Romanian, `ő` if Hungarian, `å` if Danish, and neither if English. None of the special characters occur in any other of the four languages.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Comment: @programmer5000 The OP hasn't been seen since 2011, I think you're fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Metagolf: Catlike Piet

The goal of this is to write a `cat`like program, which would be executed (in a Unix environment, though you needn't stick to that) by the following:

```
yourprogram < file > output
piet output
```

where `piet output` writes the contents of `file` to stdout.  That is, you're to generate a Piet program which prints the input to `yourprogram`.

**One-liners**

Straight line programs can be written in Piet... in straight lines.  If you're willing to take a hit to your score, your output can take the form of a string of commands:

```
=  none (continue color block)
|  push
^  pop
+  add
-  subtract
*  multiply
/  divide
%  mod
~  not
>  greater
.  pointer
\  switch
:  duplicate
@  roll
$  input number
?  input character
#  output number
!  output character
```

which is trivial to convert to a Piet program with the following (partially golfed) Python code:

```
def P(s):
 h=v=0;l=len(s)+1;R="P3 %i 2 255 192 0 0 "%(l+2)
 C=[1,3,2,6,4,5];V=[0,192,192,255,0,255]
 for x in map("=|^+-*/%~>.,:@$?#!".find,s):
  C=C[x//3:]+C[:x//3];V=V[x%3*2:]+V[:x%3*2]
  for i in [1,2,4]:R+="%i "%V[(C[0]//i)%2]
 return R+"255 "*4+"0 0 "+"255 "*l*3+"255 0 0 "*2
```

The dimension of said program is (n+3) x 2 if there are n characters in the string.

**Scoring**

Your code will be judged on the *maximum dimension* of the images that it outputs.

- Part 1: Take the maximum score taken over all ascii codes (that is, single-character inputs), discounting EOF.
- Part 2: Take the score for the input "Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die."

Your score is the product of the scores in part 1 and part 2.

Punishment: Double your score if you write one-liners as above (that is, if you don't output an image).

Bonus: If your program is written in Piet, take the square root of your score above.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the task as *"Write a program taking INPUT which produces as output a piet program that takes no input but produces INPUT."* I think it is a interesting and challenging, but it's reception will depend entirely on how many people are willing to learn/futz-around-in/deal-with piet. And I have no feel for how many that is.

Comment: @dmckee; would it be better if I just used a reduced instruction set, and only ask for the instruction stream?  I think this is still challenging with {push 1,duplicate,add,subtract,multiply,output}.  Come to think of it, if I restrict to {push 1,duplicate,add,output}, there's a reduction to some awesome algorithms.

Comment: I did this in piet some time ago: http://craigoclock.blogspot.com/2011/05/metaprogramming-in-piet.html

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 4):

### (-: Emotional Programming ;-)

Write the most emotional program you can, i.e. which consists of emoticons as much as possible.

The program should receive a word and print an appropriate emoticon.

Scoring - I'm really not sure about this, and the question will be worthless without a good scoring algorithm. I want to:
 1. Avoid giving an advantage to very short programs (e.g. `(-:`, is 100% emotional).
 2. Avoid a meaningless help of emoticons - `print '(-:' #(-:(-:(-:` and such.
 3. Prefer a variety of different emoticons.

Suggestion:
1. Count characters of code.
2. For each emoticon in the code, reduce a character.
2. For N different emoticons used, reduce further 2*N^2 characters.

What's an emoticon? Anything that somewhat resembles a face, or a closed list?

And should I ban [Emoticon](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoticon)?

Comment: My suggestion to fix scoring would be to add restrictions to the submissions' output, and have scoring be a function of their code and their output.

Comment: Thanks @jwrush, Scoring based on output seems to complicate things, and I'm already unclear about my scoring. I changed the required behavior to something more closed. Still, I don't feel the question is good enough.

Comment: This seems to have a strong bias towards GolfScript, which produces lots of emoticons naturally. It also seems hard to tighten to an objective spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I don't like a bias towards GolfScript, but if that was a reason not to post questions, this site would be much smaller. The requirement can be very tight - I can provide a list of words and emoticons, and require translation between them. I'm not sure I want to tighten this way though.

Comment: I disagree on the first point. I see a difference between GS having an advantage in code golf because it's designed to be terse, and GS having an advantage in a challenge because the challenge actively rewards a property which GS has as a side-effect of its design. Also note that I probably wouldn't be the loudest protestor against a pro-GS bias, but I think it's fair to warn you that other people might protest ;)

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I wish that was the problem. I don't really how to make this a question that triggers interesting solutions, so it looks like it stays in the sandbox.

Comment: Might want to forbid comments?

Comment: I think this would only work as a popcon

Answer (score 4):

## Count unique characters in text.

Given a string for input, output the unique non-whitespace characters in that string along with a count of their occurrences. The list should be sorted in ascending order of ASCII code.

**Examples**

Input:

```
Hello, World!
```

Output:

```
Character    Count
!            1
,            1
H            1
W            1
d            1
e            1
l            3
o            2
r            1
```

Input:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Output:

```
Character    Count
.            1
T            1
a            1
b            1
c            1
d            1
e            3
f            1
g            1
h            2
i            1
j            1
k            1
l            1
m            1
n            1
o            4
p            1
q            1
r            1
s            1
t            1
u            1
v            1
w            1
x            1
y            1
z            1
```

The actual formatting (headers, spacing, etc) of the on-screen output is up to you. The only conditions are that it must be sorted in ascending order by ASCII code, and it must be easy to tell what represents a character from the string and what represents a count of a given character. (For example, given a string of `99999999`, the output should be explicit so that it is not confused as saying I have 9 8s.)

Ultimate challenge (taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15786/9387)):

```
JKqdJg+oJgiowgyIJgkS+gyxJdeS+gyxJ4yoJdybJdioJdqIJ4kS+KwFJ4QS+gzYJg+ow4vIJ4yxvd+IJgy=+dv=JdQx+gzbJrzx24zYJgkxJ4qLJKQxJ4yxJKqx+KqdJKqdJg+oJgiowgyIJgkS+gyxJdeo24yxJm+xJdybJdioJdqIJKi=J4wF+dvS+gzYJg+ow4zYJ4yxvdy=J4i=+Kv=JdQo+KqxJrzdJKzYJgkxJ4qLJgkxJ4yxJKvSJ4qbJKqdJg+oJgiowgyIJgkdJgyxJdeo24yxJm+xJdybJd+oJd+S+dz=J4wF+dvS+g+SJg+ow4vIJ4yxJ4voJgy=+dv=+dzdJgqxJrzdJKzYJgkS+dweJKQxJ4yxJKvSJ4qbJKq=24yYJgiowgyIJgkdJgzdJryo24yxJm+d24zxJd+oJdqIJ4kS+KwFJ4QS+gzYJ4y=2gzYJ4yxJ4voJgy=+dv=+dzdJgqxJrzx24zYJgkS+dweJKQxJ4fK+dQSJ4qbJKq=24yYJgiowgyIJgkS+gzdJryS+gyxJ4yoJdybJd+oJd+S+dz=J4wF+dvS+gzYJ4y=2gvIJ4yxJ4voJgy=+dv=JdQo+KqxJrzx24zY+dzS+dweJKQxJ4yxJKqx+KqbJKq=24vbJdyowgyIJgkdJgzdJryS+gyxJm+d24zxJdioJd+S+dz=J4wF+dvS+gzYJg+ow4vIJ4yxJ4voJgy=+Kv=JdQx+gzbJrzx24zYJgkS+dweJgkxJ4yxJKvSJ4qdJKq=24yYJgiowgyIJgkdJgzdJryS+gyxJ4yoJdybJd+oJdqIJKi=J4wF+dvS+gzYJg+ow4vIJ4yxJ4v=J4i=+Kv=+dzdJgqxJrzx24zYJgkS+dweJgkxJ4fKJ4qx+KqdJKqdJg+SJdyowg+oJgkS+gyxJdeS+gyxJ4yoJdybJd+oJdqIJ4kS+KwFJ4QS+g+SJ4y=2gzYJ4yxJ4v=J4i=+Kv=JdQo+KqxJrzx24zY+dzS+dweJKQxJ4yxJKvSJ4qbJKqdJg+oJgiowg+oJgkS+gzdJryo24yxJ4yoJdybJdioJdqIJ4kS+KwFJ4QS+g+SJg+ow4vIJ4yxvd+IJgy=+dv=JdQo+KqxJrzdJKzY+dzxJ4qLJKQxJ4yxJKqx+KqdJKq=24vbJdyowg+oJgkS+gzdJryo24yxJ4yoJdybJdioJd+S+dz=J4wFJ4QS+gzYJg+ow4zYJ4yxvd+IJgy=+Kv=+dzdJgqxJrzdJKzYJgkxJ4qLJgkxJ4yxJKvSJ4qbJKq=24vbJdyowgyIJgkdJgyxJdeo24yxJm+xJdybJd+oJdqIJKi=J4wF+dvS+g+SJ4y=2gvIJ4yxvd+IJgy=+dv=+dzdJKzbJrzdJKzY+dzS+dweJgkxJ4yxJKvSJ4qbJKq=24yYJgiowg+oJgkS+gyxJdeo24yxJ4yoJKzxJd+oJdqIJKi=J4wF+dvS+gzYJg+ow4vIJ4yxJ4v=J4i=+dv=+dzdJgqxJrzx24zYJgkxJ4qLJKQxJ4fKJ4qx+KqdJKqdJg+oJgiowgyIJgkS+gzdJryS+gyxJm+d24zxJd+oJdqIJKi=J4wFJ4QS+gzYJ4y=2gzYJ4yxvdy=J4i=+Kv=+dzdJKzbJrzx24zY+dzxJ4qLJKQxJ4yxJKqx+KqdJKqdJg+SJdyowg+oJgkdJgzdJryo24yxJm+d24zxJd+5
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: This isn't really an interesting problem. The shortest answer is almost certainly going to be fewer than 10 characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor While I mostly agree with your comment - already the header line may contain more than 10 characters.

Comment: *"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."* contains *"e"* three times.

Comment: @Howard Thanks. I must be blind - it took me about five times of reading your comment to find it. Also, do remember that the header is optional to a certain degree - you just need to make sure the output is unambiguous as to which items are characters from the string, and which are character counts.

Comment: My brain instantly went into bash mode. wc and uniq practically solve half of this, but not in any particularly short manner.

Answer (score 4):

### How long until my next birthday is on a weekend

I would like to know how much time (in days) I have to wait (from now) until my birthday occurs on a weekend...

- The required tool could accept arguments or standard input.
- The only variable passed as input (as argument or stdin) is my birth day in the strict form `YYYY/MM/DD` with only digits, separated by `/` (of course: `YYYY` for birth year, `MM` for the month and `DD` for the day of month.
- The output must present the number of days to wait, from now, and the target date with the day of week, in the form `Wait DTW days to WWW, YYYY/MM/DD` where `DTW` in integer is the number of days to wait, `WWW` as day of week abbreviation could be `Sat` or `Sun` and the target date in same form as input.
- Once done, there is no more request (tool could finish quietly, loop, bug or crash)
- About February 29th, there are 3 ways you can handle it:

  - *strict*: Where birthday may occur once every 4 years
  - *right*: Where birthday is March 1st while Feb 29th doesn't exist.
  - *relax*: Where birthday could be Feb 28th or March 1st, but only while Feb 29th doesn't exist.

  The tool must match in the *right* manner, but could accept an option as choice between one of the three ways.
- Shortest golfed code wins

  - **-3** explanation (while golfed version must use *one letter* variable, ungolfed version is welcome with useful variable names)
  - **-3** if properly loop on STDIN
  - **-5** if no requirement of external library
  - **-10** if an option to choose the way of considering February 29th.
  - **0** for `shebang` (unless they contain more than *runtime options*: switch `r` in `sed` or `p` in `perl` are *runtime options*, they count for null)
  - **N** embed code on shebang line in counted normally.

Comment: How would you handle birthdays on February 29th?  It would be an interesting special case, and it will increase the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Is this going to get answers which are much different to the currently active calendar-related questions? IMO it would be best left for a couple of months. Variety is a good thing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm not sure about what to answer to this. I think: *yes in that*: there is **two** input: current day and birthday, a **range** in week, not only one day and may different thinking may build different solution...

Comment: @PhiNotPi Thanks, question edited!

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've already browsed [tag:calendar] questions ;-)

Comment: Instead of listing this as [tag:code-golf], I recommend that you list it as [tag:code-challenge] and change "Shortest golfed code" to "Lowest score" and add: **1** for each char

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to vote to delete this.

Answer (score 4):

### 3D Maze Navigation

Output a path through a 3D maze.

**Input**

The input will be from STDIN and will be a 3D maze. The maze will be input in slices horizontally across the maze starting from the top and moving down to the bottom. Each slice will be of the same width and depth, though the width, depth and number of slices could be different from run to run, and each slice will be separated by a blank line in the input. Here's an example:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****

*****
*@* *
* * *
*   *
*****

*****
*** *
*****
*****
*****

*****
*>* *
* * *
*   *
*****

*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

The `*` character represents a solid wall or floor, `@` is our hero and `>` is the exit from the maze.

**Output:**

The aim is to find if there is a way for the hero to get to the exit, and if there is, to show him the way with a series of directions:

```
SSEENNDDSSWWNN
```

Obviously this is a very simple maze, but the test cases will be harder than this. To complicate matters, the maze includes zero or more doors which can only be opened if the hero has picked up the correct key on the way. Each key is represented by a lower case character, and will only open a door represented by the uppercase version of the same letter (so `a` opens door `A`, `b` opens `B` and so on). The action of picking up a key is represented in the output with an `X`, and the hero has small hands and so can only hold one key at a time (his other hand is holding his mobile phone so he can keep track of his SO reputation). This may mean in some cases that he has to backtrack to get the next key required.

A couple of examples:

**Input:**

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****

*****
*@*>*
* *D*
*d  *
*****

*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

**Output:**

```
SSXEENN
```

The key and door have to be in the correct order, he can't use a key from beyond the door to open the door. If the maze has no solution, you should output nothing at all.

**Input:**

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****

*****
*@*>*
* *d*
*D  *
*****

*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

**Output:**

I'm providing a few test cases.

**Test case 1**

**Input**

```
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******
******                ******

******                ******
** * *                *    *
** b**                * ** *
** * *                * *  *
*  * *                * ****
* ** *                * *> *
*    *                * ** *
***A**                * ** *
*@   *                * *  *
******                ******

****************************
** * ***********************
****************************
**** ******************** **
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
**** ****************** ** *
****************************

****************************
** * *        *    **   *  *
** * * ****** * ** *  * * **
* B* *   *    * e* * ****  *
* **** * *c***** *   *   * *
*  **  * *    ** ***** **  *
**    ** ****  *        * **
*  *****C*** ** * *****E* **
*d**a***D             * *  *
****************************

****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
****************************
```

**Output** (other solutions may exist, but I think this is the shortest)

```
EEEDDXUWNNWWNNENNEXWNDDSSWSSESEEENENNNNEEEEEEESSWWWSXNEEENNWWWWWWWSSEESSSSNNNNWWSSWSWWWSWSXNENEEENENNEESSSSSEEEEEEEEENNWNNNXSSSEEEEEEESSUUNNNNNNNEEESSWDDESSWSSSEUU    NNNW
```

Comment: If W puts out F and K opens D, who specifies that? Maybe you could go abstract and say that A unlocks a, B unlocks b...

Comment: @JanDvorak The pairs of obstacles and equipment need to overcome them would be specified in the question. At the moment I'm trying to see if that's a complication too far and if I should stick to the easy version of the challenge (I think I'd prefer to post the harder version, but there's no point if no-one would answer it).

Comment: I don't mind keys and doors (somehow I like the extra challenge), but memorizing a {char x char} lookup table doesn't really serve anything.

Comment: @JanDvorak Okay, that's a fair point.

Comment: On that same note, I suggest using non-alphanumerics for the hero and exit. You can get inspired by the rougelike genre: `@` means the hero, and `>` means "stairs down" (exit). Or, you could use `<` (stairs up) for the starting point. Then the path/non-path would be dots (lit floor) vs. spaces (unlit floor).

Comment: Is the solid border guaranteed?

Comment: Yes. There will be a a solid border to each side and above and below. There will be no way to escape the maze in any of the test cases.

Comment: Also, what if there are multiple paths? Which path should we choose?

Comment: For the purposes of providing test scripts, I'd probably ensure that there was only one possible path in the tests. Maybe I should add a guarantee that that would be the case in the question?

Comment: Without the keys this is just another shortest path question, so I think the keys are essential to make it interesting. However, they potentially lead to routes which double back on themselves, and the output format doesn't handle this well. What do you think to changing the output to a string of e.g. NSEWUD?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I thought the 3D aspect might make it more interesting than another shortest path question? Yes, I'm very flexible on the output format. My biggest worry is making the test cases such that there is only one possible correct answer to make it easy for me to modify the test scripts that I already use.

Comment: 3d changes the lattice structure slightly but IMO it's a trivial change. The keys add a dimension each. To help the unique solutions you could prohibit doubling back, so that each step adds a dimension and steering AI is necessary to keep performance acceptable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is it better to prohibit doubling back or maybe only allow the holding of one key at a time (requiring doubling back to get the correct key in some cases)?

Comment: Holding one key at a time increases the state space moderately (I make it a factor of `n * 2^n`), but I expect answers would still be straight Dijkstra. It adds a complication which should be clarified: if I'm carrying a key, am I prohibited from stepping on a different key, or do I pass over it and leave it alone?

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I was to take that path you would be able to pass over keys without picking them up.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 4):

### 4 and 20 baked in a π

While some might describe π as a string of seemingly random numbers, one can also look at it in a way similar to a monkey with a typewriter.  Eventually, it should calculate out to something more interesting. For example, the sequence `1337` shows up 4,814 places to the right of the decimal. At 700,731 places right of the decimal, you'll find the sequence `160151`, which is "pi" represented as ASCII (although you'll find a 'pointer' to it much faster, as the sequence `700731` begins at 29,830 digits to the right).

So, your task is to make a program to find things in π.  Your program will accept a positive integer and output the number of places right of the decimal point that number appears.  To keep the run times down, input can be limited to numbers in the range of 0 to 1000 (without leading zeros).

Example: Using 415 as the input, the output should be 2:

```
3.14159
   ^
```

**Rules:**

- You can not use any precalculated values of π, including language
  constants, built in functions that return π or digits of π, or any
  resource outside the code itself (such as files or websites).
- You can not use any trig functions to calculate π.

Bonus points if you find the sequence `072 101 108 108 111 044 032 087 111 114 108 100 033`.

This is code golf, so lowest score wins.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you require answers to support leading zeroes. Also: program, named function or snippet? And how indexed? (Giving 415 as a test case would be a good way to answer the last question)

Comment: Isn't this just [Calculate 500 digits of pi](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/506/11006) with a search function tagged on at the end? By the way, your bonus points are quite safe — [even if you searched a trillion trillion trillion digits of pi, your chance of finding an arbitrary 39-digit sequence would still be less than 0.1%](http://www.angio.net/pi/whynotpi.html).

Comment: Edited to clarify leading zeros and indexing. @squeamishossifrage - Yes and no. The number of digits to find the answer depends on the input, which both limits the choice of algorithm to generate the search space and gives more ample room to golf the integration of the search function. The worst case is under 10000 digits for n between 0 and 1000. I suppose I could put in a time limit of a couple minutes and expand the range of n to 10000 (worst case is just under 390k), but that seems obnoxious.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AlexA. - [Not a drug reference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_a_Song_of_Sixpence)

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 4):

## ASCII ART edge detection

As the title says,  I was thinking to contest in which one must detect edges of an ASCII art.

The code should accept a B/W ASCII art as input.
A *B/W ASCII art* is defined as (by me) an *ASCII art* with only one kind of non-white-spaces character (in our case: an asteriks `*`). And as *output* produce a standard *ASCII* art (all *ASCII* characters are accepted) which should remember the contourn of the first.

The purpose of using more than one character in the output is to make some edges ssmoother.
For instance, one could let this input

```
     *** 
   ****
 ******
******
****** 
 ******
   ****
     ***
```

could became:

```
      ___
    _/   ) 
  _/    /
 /      |
|      /
|      \
 \      |
  `\     |
     \___)
```

The input `\n` separated string as input. Each line has a maximum of `80` characters. The number of rows is not specified.

I'd put it as a **popularity-contest** since, beside my simple code, I'd like to see more "round" edge detections which use more than one character in smooth edges.

Also, I don't want to tag it as **code-golf** since I'm quite sure one can do this job using `aplay` (with ASCII art renderer) and command line `GIMP` (to apply edge detection).

As a popularity contest, there are no strict rules on how the output should be..just use your fantasy!

This is my sample program:

```
import fileinput as f
import re as r
import copy as c
a,s,p='*',' ','+'
def read(n):
    s=[list(' '*n)]
    for l in f.input():
        if(len(l)>n):l=l[:n]
        k=list(r.sub('[^ ^\%c]'%a,'',' '+l+' '))
        s.append(k+[' ']*(n-len(k)))
    s.append([' ']*n)
    return s
def np(s):
    s=c.deepcopy(s)
    for l in s[1:-1]:
        for w in l[1:-1]: print(w,end='')
        print()
def grow(i):
    o=c.deepcopy(i)
    for x in range(1,len(o)-1):
        for y in range(1,len(o[x])-1):
            if(i[x][y]==a): o[x-1][y-1]=o[x-1][y+1]=o[x-1][y]=o[x+1][y]=o[x+1][y-1]=o[x+1][y+1]=o[x][y+1]=o[x][y-1]=a

    return o
def diff(i,o):
    c=[]
    for x in range(0,len(i)):
        l=[]
        for y in range(0,len(i[x])):
            if(i[x][y]==a and o[x][y]==s): l.append(p)
            else: l.append(s)
        c.append(l)
    return c
I=read(80)
np(diff(grow(I),I))
```

Here below I put both input of the programs. It is an 80x70 ASCII ART. It means it has 70 lines of 80 characters, each separated by `\n`.

```
                                              *************
                                          *****          *****                   
                                     ******                  ***                 
                                    ***                         ****             
                             *********                             **            
                          ***********                               **           
                     ******   *******                                **          
                 *****       *******      ***                         **         
              ****          ********     *****                          *        
             **            *********     *****                    *****  *       
           ***            *********     *******                  ******  **      
          **             **********     *******                  ******   **     
         **              **********    *******                  ********   *     
        *               ***********   ******                    ********   *     
       **              ************   *****                     ********    *    
       *               ************    ***                       ********   *    
      *               *************                               ******    *    
     *                *************                                 ***     *    
    **                *************                                         *    
    *                **************                                         *    
   **                *************                                         **    
   *                 *************                                         **    
  **                *************                                          ***   
 ***                *************                                          ****  
 **                 ************                                           ****  
 **                *************                                           ****  
 **                *************           *****                           ****  
 **                *************          **   **          **              ****  
 **                 ************          *     *         ** **            ****  
 *                  ************          **   **        **   **           ****  
 *                  *************        *******         **   ***          ****  
 *                  ************          *****           *******          ****  
 *                   ************         ***               *****          ****  
**     *             *************                          ****          *****  
**    ***            **************                                      *****   
*    *****            *************                                     ******   
** *******             **************                                  *******   
**********             ***************              *                *********   
**********              *****************          ***             ***********   
***********              *******************                    **************   
***********               **********************            ******************   
************              *****************     **     ***********************   
*************             ******************      ****     *******************   
**************            ******************              ********************   
****************           ******************              *******************   
***************           *******************              *******************   
****************           ******************              ******************    
******************         ******************             *******************    
*******************         *****************             *******************    
*********************      ******************           ********************     
*********************************************          *********************     
**********************************************       ***********************     
************************     *****************      ************************     
 **********************       ******************* **************************     
 *********************        *********************************************      
 *********************        ****************************  ***************      
 ********************         **************************    ***************      
 ********************         *********************         ***************      
 *******************          ********************         ****************      
 ******************           *****************            ****************      
 *****************             ****************            ***************       
 *****************             ****************            ***************       
 *****************             *****************           ***************       
  ****************             *****************           ***************       
   **************              ******************          ***************       
                                 ****************          ****************      
                                  **************            ***************      
                                                             **************      
                                                              ************
```

A possible output could be:

```
                                         +++++             ++++
                                    ++++++     ++++++++++     +++
                                   ++      +++++        +++++   +++++
                            ++++++++   +++++                ++++    ++
                         ++++         ++                       ++++  ++
                    ++++++           ++                           ++  ++
                +++++      +++       +   +++++                     ++  ++
             ++++     +++++++       ++  ++   ++                     ++  ++
            ++    +++++   ++        +   +     +                  +++++++ ++
          +++  ++++      ++         +  ++     ++                ++     ++ ++
         ++   ++        ++         ++  +       +                +      ++  ++
        ++  +++         +          +  ++       +               ++      +++  +
       ++  ++          ++          + ++       ++               +        +++ +
      ++ +++          ++           + +      +++                +        + + ++
      +  +            +            + +     ++                  +        ++++ +
     ++ ++           ++            + ++   ++                   ++        + + +
    ++ ++            +             +  +++++                     ++      ++ + +
   ++ ++             +             +                             +++   ++  + +
   +  +             ++             +                               +++++   + +
  ++ ++             +              +                                      ++ +
  +  +              +             ++                                      +  +
 ++ ++             ++             +                                       +  ++
++  +              +             ++                                       +   ++
+   +              +             +                                        +    +
+  ++             ++            ++                                        +    +
+  +              +             +         +++++++                         +    +
+  +              +             +        ++     ++        ++++            +    +
+  +              +             +        +  +++  +       ++  +++          +    +
+  +              ++            +        + ++ ++ +      ++  +  ++         +    +
+ ++               +            ++      ++  +++  +      +  +++  ++        +    +
+ +                +             +      +       ++      +  +++   +        +    +
+ +                +            ++      ++     ++       ++       +        +    +
+ +   +++          ++            ++      +   +++         +++     +       ++    +
  +  ++ ++          +             ++     +++++             +    ++      ++     +
  + ++   ++         +              +                       ++++++      ++     ++
 ++++     +         ++             +++                                ++      +
  +       +          ++              ++            +++              +++       +
          +           +               ++++        ++ ++           +++         +
          ++          ++                 ++++     +   +        ++++           +
           +           ++                   +++++ +++++    +++++              +
           ++           ++                      +++   ++++++                  +
            ++           +                 +++++  +++++                       +
             ++          +                  +  +++    +++++                   +
              +++        +                  ++   ++++++  +                    +
                +        ++                  +           ++                   +
               ++        +                   +            +                   +
                +++      ++                  +           ++                  ++
                  ++      +                  +           +                   +
                   +++    ++                 +         +++                   +
                     ++++++                  +        ++                    ++
                                             ++     +++                     +
                                              +    ++                       +
                        +++++                 ++++++                        +
+                      ++   ++                   +                          +
+                     ++     +                                             ++
+                     +      +                            ++               +
+                    ++      +                          ++++               +
+                    +       +                     ++++++ ++               +
+                   ++       +                    ++      +                +
+                  ++        +                 ++++       +                +
+                 ++         ++                +          +               ++
+                 +           +                ++         +               +
+                 +           +                 +         +               +
++                +           +                 ++        +               +
 ++              ++           +                  +        +               ++
  ++++++++++++++++            +++                +        +                +
                                ++              ++        ++               +
                                 ++++++++++++++++          ++              +
                                                            ++            ++
                                                             ++++++++++++++
```

This is also the output produced by the script above. Of course it is not the best output and I'm sure  one can easily produce a smoother one.

Comment: It would be useful to be more precise about which characters should be non-blank in the output: characters which were non-blank in the input but adjacent to blanks, or characters which were blank in the input but adjacent to non-blanks?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I re-written the phrase in the answer. You can use every ASCII character in the output (as usual ASCII art). E.g. I used only `+` symbol, but one could makes round edges using symbols like `\ ` or `/` etc..

Comment: edited again...

Comment: Can you define the input that will be used by all the participants? It's necessary to have only one input to compare the outputs of the different answers. The first example is too simple and the last one is too long. So I suggest to use something between these 2 examples.

Comment: Thanks, I chosen a cute panda as input.

Comment: _one could let this input (…) could became_ → try something like "this input (…) could become" _outpuit_ → output

Comment: I edited it now, so do you people thinks it is a good question?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: Hi @programmer5000 , I already asked such a question. Do you mean to re-use it again? See: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/ascii-art-edge-detection

Answer (score 4):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

## Ping an IP address continually and report the dropped to returned ratio

Create a console program that pings an IP address at most once per second and reports the ratio of dropped to returned packets to the screen in real time.

The IP address will be provided on the command line in standard IPv4 notation.  (eg. 192.168.0.1)

The 'ping' method should be ICMP echo (See [here](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/icmp-protocol/152-icmp-echo-ping.html) for a summary of ICMP packet structure) with a packet size of at least 32 bytes.

Your program must be "standalone" and cannot rely on external programs, libraries, or resources.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so let the shortest answer win

Comment: `ping` isn't enough?

Comment: ping works great, except you have to tell it when to stop to get the final tally

Comment: I think you're assuming that everyone will interpret this as sending the same ICMP control packet that `ping` sends, but it would be an improvement to the question both to make this explicit and to link to some documentation about ICMP.

Comment: Actually I left it ambiguous.  Any IP request that elicits a response can be considered a ping.

Comment: Alright, lets make it easier and say ICMP specifically...

Comment: Well this doesn't have enough upvotes...I'll leave it in the sandbox, but likely it will not be posted

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: @programmer5000 be my guest :)

Answer (score 4):

## Find sociable numbers

#### Background

A number is perfect if it is the sum of its divisors; for instance `6=1+2+3`

A pair of numbers is friendly if they are the sum of each other's divisors; for instance `284=1+2+4+5+10+11+20+22+44+55+110` and `220=1+2+4+71+142`.

In general, a list of n numbers is sociable if each element is the sum of divisors of the previous elements, with the first being the sum of divisors of the last.

#### Input

An integer, `n` on STDIN.

#### Output

A list of `n` numbers which are sociable, in the order outlined above, each on its own line. If you can't find any suitable list, you may output nothing, `False`, or `0`, but you must search up to at least `2^32-1`, and preferably as high as your language will allow

#### Winning

This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins. However, I will also create a bounty to be awarded to the fastest program, as measured on my command-line (Windows 7 with GNU coreutils, python27, python3, node.js, perl) or in a web IDE in chrome (brainfuck, golfscript?)

Edit: to clarify the relationship between input and output

Comment: The relation between the input and output is unclear. Are we asked to find the loop of sociable numbers that the input number leads to by iterating "sum of proper divisors"?

Comment: @JanDvorak, no, we're asked to find a cycle of length `n` in the directed graph whose vertices are the natural numbers and whose edges are `i -> aliquot_sum(i)`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have a code golf and a fastest code challenge in the same problem. You'll get incomparable answers. Maybe make a composite score that incorporates time and length?

Comment: That may be better.

Comment: Would you allow the usage of predefined functions that calculate the aliquot sum?

Comment: @alexander-brett Are you going to post this?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 4):

**Save your job in QA!**

You work for a software company's QA department, writing automated acceptance tests for their products. One day, your boss calls you in to his office, and to your astonishment tells you that your entire department is being "rationalized".

"But why?" You ask

"One of the fellows in development told me about these new-fangled things called 'unit tests'. Apparently, you can test each little bit of code as you write it. And since the developers do it themselves, that means we don't need a QA department any more."

You hesitate. "Well unit tests *are* a good idea, but you still need-"

"Nonsense!" Your boss blusters, cutting you off mid-sentence "If we can test every little bit of the code, we don't need to test the whole lot again!"

Your boss is adamant, but after a bit of wrangling, he grants you one chance: later that day, you will present him with a demonstration proving that unit tests alone aren't enough to test your product.

**The challenge**

Your challenge is to write the following:

- A *system under test* with more than one part
- *Unit tests* for each part
- One or more *integration tests*, consisting of multiple parts working together

The unit tests should appear to prove that the system under has one behaviour, while the integration tests should prove that it actually has another.

**Guidelines**

This is a **popularity contest**, and the following criteria should be taken into account for rating the answers:

- The trick leading to the unit tests having different conclusions to the integration tests should be primarily in the system under test. Your boss won't be impressed if all you did was insert a bug into one of your tests!
- The more convincingly the individual unit tests and integration tests appear to prove what they are each attempting to test, the better.
- The more convincingly the conclusions of the integration tests appear to contradict the unit tests, the better. For example, an answer where both the unit tests and integration tests use the same inputs to the system under test would probably be better than one that relies on them using different inputs. An answer where the integration test tests some behaviour of the system which was clearly not covered by the unit tests would also not be a very good answer.

Tests may be written in whatever format is appropriate for the language you are using. Two possibilities which would work in many situations would be:

- Tests have no return value, but throw an exception (or equivalent) if they fail
- Tests return `true` for a pass or `false` for a fail

Answer (score 4):

## Cube puzzle

Write a program that can determine whether or not a collection of puzzle pieces can be assembled to form a solid cube. The pieces can be moved and rotated, but not reflected.

Each puzzle piece consists of a connected set of sub-cubes. The arrangement of these sub-cubes is described an ASCII representation consisting of a single line with three space-separated numbers *x*, *y* and *z*, followed by *z* blocks of *x × y* characters where `X` represents an occupied sub-cube, and `.` represents an empty sub-cube. The first line of input indicates the number of puzzle pieces that follow (*N*).

### Input/output:

Your program should accept input from stdin, and should print its results to stdout. If the pieces can form a cube, it should output the line "CUBE". If not, it should output "NOT A CUBE".

### Example:

[image]

In the above illustration, a 3×3×3 cube is constructed from five pieces. If the pieces are listed in the order {pink, yellow, blue, red, green}, then the input could look something like this:

```
5
3 2 1
X..
XXX
3 2 2
XXX
X..
...
X..
3 3 2
...
.X.
...
XXX
.X.
XX.
2 3 1
XX
XX
.X
3 3 2
X..
X..
X..
...
...
XXX
```

### Limits:

Your program should be able to handle any puzzle comprising up to 10×10×10 sub-cubes.

### Winning criterion:

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. The shortest answer (measured in bytes of code) will win.

Comment: This is a nice idea but the input format seems complicated. I have another idea: use directions to define the pieces. For example for the pink piece: `.RRU` (start, then go to `R`ight twice then go to `U`p). Directions are `U`p, `R`ight, `D`owm, `L`eft, `F`ront and `B`ack.

Comment: OK, but how would that work for pieces that contain branches (like the blue one, for example)?

Comment: Ah, I forgot this case. :-) I think we can use a direction to get back from the branch to the trunk. For example for the blue one: `.RTTBFTLRR` (the point is view is located at the left of your image)

Comment: @A.L what does `T` signify?

Comment: @githubphagocyte oops, I wrote `T` for `T`op, it's `U` instead.

Comment: @A.L so `.RUUBFULRR`? Makes sense now thank you.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: @programmer5000 You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck compression [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Possible Duplicate

As it stands, this challenge could be labelled as a duplicate of others, as it is a base conversion. Please suggest ways of avoiding this in the comments. (Perhaps make interpreting the compressed code part of the challenge?)

### Challenge

For many code golfers, Brainfuck is the language of choice. However, it is horrifyingly wasteful: it only uses eight symbols (`.,<>+-[]`) out of a character set of 256.

Your task is to convert it into a compressed format, as follows:

1. Receive Brainfuck code on standard input or equivalent.
2. Remove characters which are not `.,<>+-[]`.
3. Convert `[` to `000`, `]` to `001`, `+` to `010`, `-` to `011`, `.` to `100`, `,` to `101`, `<` to `110` and `>` to `111`.
4. Group the resulting string into bytes, e.g. `,[.,]` becomes `10100010 01010011`.
5. If the last "byte" is fewer than 8 bits long, add ones until it is 8 bits long. (Note: these may get interpreted as `>` instructions when the code is run or decompressed, but since they are at the end of the program, it doesn't matter.)
6. Output the bytes to standard output.

Note: If the input does not contain any Brainfuck characters, the output should be empty.

### Todo

Could this challenge include decompression as well?

Would a separate challenge for decompression or directly interpreting the compressed code be a duplicate?

Possible bonuses: -50 for removing `<>`, `><`, `+-`, `-+` from the code (golfing)

Comment: Nice challenge! I think it would be appropriate to include decompression aswell personally. The NULL byte could be an issue, especially for C programmers, but as you said, as long as you don't use two consecutive `[`s, everything should be okay

Comment: Also, you might add information about how non-brainfuck characters should be handled (e.g. if you provide `abcd` as input)

Comment: @HackerCow I'm trying to keep it simple, so I'm not sure about the decompression or interpreting. As a pure code-golf, would you just ask for two programs? (could be separated into two questions) Alternatively, it could be a code-reuse challenge, where the compressor and the decompressor/intepreter have to be as similar as possible (score=`program1length+program2length+levenshteindistance`)

Comment: Well you could potentially ask this one now and post a "sequel" to it later, handling the decompression part. The code-reuse would also be a great idea, but that would definetely be a challenge ;)

Comment: @HackerCow I'm worried that a separate decompression challenge might be a dupe of this one...

Comment: True, although I have seen sequels to questions before, so I don't think it would be a problem... Some mod might be able to help here

Comment: @professorfish You could ask for two programs/functions, and take the sum of both lengths as score.

Comment: @ProgramFOX True, but if the two programs aren't really connected, maybe it is better to have two separate challenges - the only problem is that they might be considered dupes...???

Comment: @professorfish Yes, they might be considered dupes, as a decompressing algorithm for this is probably the compression one reversed. But if you don't like having both in one challenge, you can also create a compression challenge without decompression.

Comment: This is just a base conversion with unusual digits, so it's essentially a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4423/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor There is a base conversion involved, although it isn't the only thing there is. would having the user create two programs, a compressor and an interpreter of the compressed data, be better?

Comment: Ok, the compression also involves a filter, but that's a trivial pre-processing step before the base conversion task which has already been done. IMO base conversion is a trivial task per se, and since [Interpret BF](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84/194) has been done I would regard an interpreter of the compressed data as also being a dupe. See also http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1571/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor OK. "Alternatively, it could be a code-reuse challenge, where the compressor and the decompressor/intepreter have to be as similar as possible (score=program1length+program2length+levenshteindistance)" - is that a dupe as well?

Comment: How about simply `score = compressorLength - decompressorLength`

Comment: @Kroltan so the longer the decompressor the better?

Comment: @professorfish Woop's that's a typo. I should stop usng the keypad to type operators. Should be a `+`. Can't edit anymore, sadly.

Comment: @Kroltan the reason why I don't like that is because the two parts aren't connected

Comment: I think this would be less likely to be considered a duplicate if the method of compression was not so strictly defined. For example, allowing the use of [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) instead of fixed length 4 bit codes may allow better compression for programs of non-trivial length. You could allow people to come up with their own method of compression and including the compressed sizes of a list of test programs in their score. Alternatively you could base the score purely on the compressed size and not limit the size of the compression program.

Comment: i think this shouldn't be code-golf; i would do it so that scoring would depend on the amount of compression / optimization that the answer does. for example, a program who optimizes ++++++++++++ to ++++[>++++<-] when possible would get a better score. the score may be calculated by using random tests (this has the advantage that the coders cannot make their solution to cope especially well with the benchmarks), but it's just .

Comment: I think the example for `,[.,]` is wrong. It should be `10100010 0101001` (second-last digit in second byte is wrong). Consequently, it translates to `)` and not `S`.

Comment: @IngoBürk do you mean the extra `1` on the end? that's intentional

Comment: @professorfish Oh dear. My mistake, I just can't count. My second byte is only 7 bits, which of course is incorrect. Never mind :)

Comment: There's no such thing as ó in ASCII. The page you linked uses IBM CP437 and calls it "extended ASCII", but it's not really relevant to anything post-1990s. I would delete any reference to character encoding and say that programs should output the bytes to stdout.

Comment: @hobbs ok, i will edit this in

Answer (score 4):

## Paired Programming: Down Periscope!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

> This is very basic for now, and lacks specific numbers as I flesh out the details and play with the speeds involved. I/O will be pretty basic, but it's not fully outlined yet.

Four submarines are placed in an arena, two on each team. They shoot torpedoes at each other. The objective, as obvious as it seems, it to kill the opposing team.

Teams are made from all pairwise matches of entries. They are then placed in a tournament-style bracket, deep enough to fit all of them. Any empty spaces are filled with a team of two dummy submarines, effectively creating a bye assuming you don't lose to a team that quite literally can't kill you.

The tournament is played several (many?) times to tally points. The team with the most points at the end is the winning team. In the interests of selecting a single winner, the winning team's bots will be compared. Whoever got the most points *total* (even from their participation on other teams) is the overall winner. Note that this means the single bot with the most points may not win (due to not being on the winning *team*).

### Sensors down, Captain

Unfortunately, you've lost most of your communications ability, and your navigation sensors are limited. Specifically, you have two ways to figure out what's around you and/or communicate: passive and active.

- **Passive Audio:** Since water is such a great conductor of sound, you can hear things from a pretty good distance. Of course, today's submarines can run pretty quietly, but as they speed up, they get louder. You can also hear other things, like active torpedoes, explosions, and sonar pings. For each of these events, you will receive a bearing (azimuth/elevation) and a loudness. Loudness drops off with distance, so you may not be able to hear everything in the arena. You don't have to directly ask for this information, it will be supplied on each turn.
- **Active Sonar:** When that just isn't good enough, there's sonar. When you activate a sonar ping, you will receive a bearing and distance to all objects (submarines/torpedoes). Of course, other subs will also be able to hear *you* when you do.

(*Tentative*) As a bonus, you can modulate a short message onto the sonar ping to communicate with other subs. This message can be up to **16 bytes** in length. Just remember, *all* other subs will be able to hear this message, not just your teammate. They will hear it as an addition to the ping during passive listening. If you have idea about how to make this useful/effective, I'm usually [available in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

### Take us down

Movement is based on vectors, and any movement commands you give are applied. Acceleration is a fcator in speed and direction, so you can't go from full stop to all out in one step. To move, you need three values: left/right, up/down, and throttle.

- **Left/Right:**  Supplied in absolute degrees from north. There is a maximum turn rate, so the ship will slowly come about to face the new heading. If the value is out of the bounds `0<=d<=359` it will be modulus 360. The ship will turn in whichever direction would result in the shorter turn, so if you want to make a 270-degree clockwise turn from north, you'll need to do it in increments of something <= 180. If you set a heading exactly 180 degrees from current, it will turn clockwise.
- **Up/Down:** Supplied in absolute degrees of the desired angle. The ship will slowly come to the desired angle. Min/max to be determined.
- **Throttle:** Supplied in meters/second desired speed. The ship will accelerate at a rate of (TBD) until desired rate is achieved (up to maximum of TBD). You cannot move backward(negative speed). **This makes noise!** The faster you are moving, the louder your sub is.

### Fire torpedoes!

You have two torpedo tubes, and an unlimited supply of torpedoes. When you fire one, it will take some time to reload, so your effective firing rate is 2/x(tbd) seconds. You don't have to specify which tube you're firing, the command will fire whichever is ready.

Torpedoes start off moving at the sub's current speed plus a small boost (to prevent detonation with firing sub). It then accelerates up to full speed. Torpedoes **home in* on any sub within their cone of vision, and will try to turn to hit whichever of these is the closest. Although a torpedo's max speed is higher than a sub's, it cannot turn as quickly, so evasive maneuvers need to be considered.

Torpedoes have distance sensors, and will blow up when they are within x(tbd) meters of a sub. This will destroy the sub, and be very audible. Torpedoes have a maximum travel distance of (tbd) meters, at which point they fizzle out and are no longer a hazard.

### The Arena

The arena is a spherical area of ocean with the origin at the center and a radius of 1000m(?tbd). Coordinates are continuous. Subs will start near the perimeter, at 90 degree intervals around the equator. They will start facing the center, with teammates 180 degrees apart. **Moving outside the sphere is death, and will be audible.**

---

---

Now obviously I've still got some work to do here, but as usual any comments are welcome. Well, *most* comments are welcome.

Comment: How does the movement work? Angle adjustments applied first and then a single linear step? (Making sure that everyone can easily predict their own position is essential to not having people complaining that they didn't move outside the sphere).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, turns both horizontal and vertical applied before the step forward. On that note, I've *thought* about getting rid of the sphere and making it toruslike, but I'm undecided.

Comment: I think that making it wrap (which I assume is what you mean) would be a conceptual headache when it comes to interpreting pings and trying to integrate longitudinal data.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Agreed, that's why it's a sphere as it is. If I could think of a good way to do it without making the boundary insta-kill, though, I would. Just avoiding the walls might be enough to put some people off, since turns aren't instant and you have to figure out your turn radius from your current speed.

Comment: One way would be to introduce a speed limitation beyond the boundary, but that would require very careful explanation to ensure that everyone's simulations agree. (Actually, on the subject of simulations agreeing: you might need to say something about using strictfp in languages like Java).

Comment: One possibility for the boundary: Instead of killing you it just prevents you from moving outside it and makes a loud noise when you bump into it or scrape along it.

Comment: Instead of making the boundary itself insta-kill you could just surround the arena with mines which increase in density the farther away from the center you travel.

Answer (score 4):

## Realistic Stock Market

This is based off of this [other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36166/stack-exchange-stock-exchange-tournament), but with a *whole lot* of added realism.  I'm trying to add as much realism as possible.  It is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge.

You are an entrepreneur in the stock market, having created your own hedge fund (correct term?).  Your company buys and sells shares in other companies, but also sells shares in itself.

At the very end of the game, the money is redistributed: All the money you've earned* is split up amongst your shareholders.  Likewise, you gain money from the companies in which you've invested.  By selling shares in yourself, there is a trade-off between long- and short-term gains.

There is a finite amount of each stock in the game, and there is one type of stock per company (so one per entrant).  Your bot will start out with `100` shares of each other company, along with `100*N` shares of itself, where `N` is the number of entrants.  Each bot will have an initial bankroll of `10000 * N`. (This helps to ensure a sufficiently large initial stock price).

### Buying and Selling

Buying and selling stock is done by placing buy and sell orders.  Each time a buy/sell order is placed, it is matched with the existing buy/sells orders to complete the trade.

Here is an example of how the orders are matched with each other for one stock:

```
 Before:
  Sell Orders:
   19 @ $20 - Bot A
   11 @ $21 - Bot B
  Buy Orders:
   06 @ $19 - Bot S #oldest is given preference 
   06 @ $19 - Bot Q
   13 @ $18 - Bot T
   22 @ $16 - Bot R

 New Order:
  Sell 26 @ $17 - Bot C
  Trades [06 @ $19 - Bot S] with a surplus of 20
  Trades [06 @ $19 - Bot Q] with a surplus of 14
  Trades [13 @ $18 - Bot T] with a surplus of 01
  No more matches

 After:
  Sell Orders:
   01 @ $17 - Bot C #the remainder of the sell order
   19 @ $20 - Bot A
   11 @ $21 - Bot B
  Buy Orders:
   22 @ $16 - Bot R
```

In this particular example, Bot C will manage to sell 26 shares for `12*19+13*18+1*17 = $479`, assuming that someone will eventually buy that one remaining share.  The bot receives $462 at the end of his turn, and would receive the $17 at the end of the buyer's turn.  If the share is not bought in the time between one turn and the next, the bot would receive that remaining share back.

### The Tournament Setup

The tournament will be composed of 10 games, with each game consisting of 365 trading rounds.  Each trading round will consist of one turn for each bot, with the bots in a randomized order.

There is nothing special that happens between any particular round.  This helps to smooth out game flow so that each bot will have equal opportunity on their turn.

At the end of each game, the money of each competitor is redistributed to its stock holders **(how much of the money?)**.

The winner of the tournament will be the bot with the highest average amount of money at the end of each game.

### A Single Turn

For each stock, the bot will receive the buy and sell orders available.

At the start of every bot's turn, that bot's previous unfulfilled sell/buy orders will be canceled.  **(Is this a good idea?).**  Any unsold stock or unspent money is returned to the player.

Then, the bot will output the list of buy/sell orders it would like to place.  The bot will be able to place one buy/sell order per stock.  The bot must be able to immediately set aside the shares/money to support the order.

The controller program will look through your sell and buy orders sequentially and will remove the assets from you that are required for the transaction.  If you have insufficient funds, that order will be ignored completely.

Then, the orders will be processed.  Orders that match the already-existing orders will allow the transaction to occur after the bot's turn.  Orders that are unmatched will remain on the market until the start of the bot's next turn.

### Recording the past

Your bot is allow to create 1 text file to maintain a history of stock prices.

### Input

Input will consist of 3 arguments in this order:

```
Current round number, which is a number 1-365
Which stock ticker is for your company
A list of the data for each stock
```

The data for the stocks will be formatted like this:

```
"[stock ticker #1],[quantity 1],[price 1],[quantity 2],[price 2] [stock ticker #2],[quantity 1],[price 1],[quantity 2],[price 2]"
```

Each quantity/price pair represents one buy or sell order.  Sell orders have positive quantity, while buy orders have negative quantity.

The order of the stocks will be randomized, but the stock tickers will remain consistent for the whole game.

(I was also think of including some more data in here, what else might be needed?  Data on the assets of all the other competitors?)

### Output:

Output will consist of many lines, each line formatted like so:

```
[stock number 1-N] [action] [quantity] [price]
```

The stock number is a number 1-N representing which stock to buy or sell.  The action can be either `b` for buy or `s` for sell.  The quantity and price can be any positive integer.

---

Notes:

I want price to have 2 decimal digits, but I don't know if that would exclude anything or make it unnecessarily complicated.  Right now, the prices are limited to integers.  There is approximately $50 for each stock in the game, in an attempt to increase smoothness.

We need to balance the number of actions allowed per turn with the number of rounds in a game.  Right now, the player can make 1 order per stock in a single round, which may make the time flow too roughly.  The more rounds played, and the fewer actions allowed per turn, the smoother the game will be.

*We need to determine exactly how the money is redistributed.  I initially had the idea that all the money will be redistributed equally to each stock, so a player who sells all the shares in himself keeps none of the money he earned in game and only gets the money from the other stocks.  I think it might make more sense to only distribute profits, but we would have to determine how much of the profits are redistributed to shareholders.

Is it a good idea to have orders cancel after a period of time?  Currently, a bot's orders are cancelled upon that bot's next turn.  If we reduce the number of moves per turn, then we would want to increase the longevity of the orders.  Alternatively, we could make orders permanent and irrevocable, only being cancelled at the end of the game.

Comment: If you give priority to orders that are older, then it makes sense to let orders persist beyond one turn.

Comment: Alternatively you could give priority to larger orders, in which case the priority would not affect your decision on whether to cancel orders after one turn.

Comment: The number of decimal places is largely irrelevant - a fixed number of decimal places is equivalent to integer. It's probably easier to model as integers internally, even if you display as 2 decimal places. You could just state that prices are in pennies/cents.

Comment: If a bot is limited in the number of buy and sell orders it can place by its available funds and shares, then that might be enough. If someone does decide to place a buy order on every single company, that will mean spreading their funds thinly as they cannot place buy orders that sum to more than the cash they have available. This naturally limits the activity level each turn.

Comment: I would recommend allowing orders to be placed and cancelled at any time. I don't think a restriction is necessary. What might make it more interesting is to introduce a cost to buying and/or selling. This should make strategy more important.

Comment: Costs could be of two types: a percentage commission on each successful sale or purchase, and also a fee for placing or cancelling an order. So bots will have to weigh up their options - to cancel an order they are uncertain they still want or leave it open to avoid a fee.

Comment: There's also a big decision to be made on how the market works. At present the prices are based purely on speculation of what those same prices will be in future. The alternative is to also have some non-player companies modelling companies selling products rather than just investing. Say 4 companies, one each for flour, eggs, rice and treacle. Those companies pay out dividends based on the randomly varying company profit, then bots use that income to pay out dividends based on how well they did out of the companies they are invested in.

Comment: I think that making each bot specify up front how much it will pay out in dividends would be good. It adds some asymmetry in round 1 (so it's not just picking a random share to buy). Probably do it in integer permille and round down when the time comes to distribute. It might even be interesting to make dividend payouts quarterly so that they don't just affect the final score.

Comment: I'd like to see the dividend percentage able to be changed, so that bots can decide to start paying out more/less at certain intervals. Maybe once a quarter.

Comment: So the bots are just buying and selling shares of each other, not any outside entity? What reason is there to choose one bot to invest in over another? Player decisions that someone's bot idea looks promising?

Comment: @xnor There are a few ideas to kick-start trading which have not been decided on yet, such as allowing the bots to announce the permille they will pay in dividends.

Answer (score 4):

## Comment Java Code

Little Billy is in an AP computer science class and his teacher requires him to comment his code (in Java) even though Little Billy thinks it is redundant. Little Billy is a lazy person and so he wants a program to comment for him.

### The Challenge:

Make a program in any language that gets a text file as input and saves the commented version to a new text file (or to STDOUT) changing it in the following ways:

- Add comments before all contructors:

> /**
>       * Constructs a new instance of *(class whatever)*.
>       * *if applicable:* @param *nameOfVariable* is the name of variable
>       */

- Add comments before any functions:

> /**
>       * *if applicable:* @param *nameOfVariable* is the name of variable.
>       * *if applicable:* @return *nameOfReturnVariable* is the name of return variable.
>       */

- Add a comment before static void main(String[] args) if present:

> /**
>       * This is where the program starts.
>       * @param  args is the command line arguments passed to the program.
>       */

- Add comments before the class declaration (not applicable for inner classes)

> /**
>       * class *NameOfClass* is another great example of Object Oriented Programming!
>       */

For example, given this:

```
public class Car {
    private double gas;
    private double mpg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Car(20,20);
    }

    public Car(){}

    public Car(double gasInVehicle, double milesPerGallon){
        gas = gasInVehicle;
        mpg = milesPerGallon;
    }

    public void drive(double milesToDrive){
        gas-=(milesToDrive/mpg);
    }

    public double getGas(){
        double gasolineInTank = gas;
        return gasolineInTank;
    }

}
```

Your program should output this:

```
/**
 * class Car is another great example of Object Oriented Programming!
 */
public class Car {
    private double gas;
    private double mpg;
    /**
     * @param args is the command line arguments passed to the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Car(20,20);
    }
    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of Car.
     */
    public Car(){}
    /**
     * Constucts a new instance of Car.
     * @param gasInVehicle is the gas in vehicle.
     * @param milesPerGallon is the miles per gallon.
     */
    public Car(double gasInVehicle, double milesPerGallon){
        gas = gasInVehicle;
        mpg = milesPerGallon;
    }
    /**
     * @param milesToDrive is the miles to drive
     */
    public void drive(double milesToDrive){
        gas-=(milesToDrive/mpg);
    }
    /**
     * @return gasolineInTank is the gasoline in tank.
     */
    public double getGas(){
        double gasolineInTank = gas;
        return gasolineInTank;
    }
}
```

### Extended Info

- Because Little Billy's class is only on week 3, Little Billy's knowledge of complex Java statements is pretty limited. In other words, only common functions, class declarations, constructors and instance variables will be included; objects/variables/resources are limited to Java primitives and their wrapper classes and Math.
- Each variable name is separated for its definition according to standard camel case rules, with an exception of the first letter, which may be capitalized. For example,

> milesToRun = miles to run.
>   milestoRun = milesto run.
>   MilesToRun = miles to run.
>   parseXML = parse xml - each successive capital letter (with a minimum of 3 in a row) is considered an acronym, so GetABuffer would become get a buffer. parseXM is parse x m.

If it is a parameter -

> @param milesToRun is the miles to run.

- Your program should be able to handle multiple arguments to functions
- There should be no lines with only " * ".
- Assume all variables and parameters are formatted correctly (e.g. all camel case, only letters, etc.)
- Indentation is not critical. However, all newlines should remain.
- You may also assume that statements ending in a semicolon are 1 line each

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins (in bytes).

Comment: when you say "assume all camel case"... what about the unlikely method name `GetABuffer`? If that is valid and should produce "get a buffer", then what about `ParseXML`?

Comment: Similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3241/194 . The thing that would potentially make this more difficult is parsing Java, but then you need to provide some details on the grammar. I also notice that your spec and examples avoid all of the tricky stuff around generics.

Comment: I think it should be `parseXml`.

Answer (score 4):

## Coloring Book

Given a black-and-white raster line drawing (no anti-aliasing, with fully enclosed regions), write a program that will color it in. Something maybe like below, though I'd clean up messy JPGs into clean B&W PNGs to start with:

http://wallalay.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Coloring-Books-27.jpg

Could either be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), to give freedom in create more interesting output (gradients, patterns, how to select "better" colors, other images).  Along the lines of patterns and gradients, I'd opt for simpler stock "prompts", preferably animals, to show off solutions:

http://www.frontiernet.net/~goofis1/Images/Dinosaurs/SlateBack.jpg

...or perhaps [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) if each region has a specified color given by a swatch inside it: so the program would basically need to find-the-color then flood-fill. Sounds boring, I prefer more creativity.

Comment: The flood fill would indeed be quite trivial, but as a popularity contest this could become too much of an art contest and less of a programming contest.

Comment: In my mind's eye I kinda pictured an  elementary school classroom wall with the same line drawing jazzed up every which way.

Comment: I do think there is reasonable technical skill involved in creating something to dynamically create said art. Gradients, patterns, masking other images into regions, coloring outside the lines, and something even more interesting than what I can come up with all seem to take reasonable skill. Especially for a few arbitrary input drawings.

Comment: If you can come up with a testable criterion, you might be able to get an interesting [tag:code-golf] which asks for cel shading rather than just floodfill.

Comment: You could specify a rule for which colour should be used. For example, you could colour based on area or perimeter of the region being filled (or some combination of both). This would colour similar regions in similar colours and give the impression of being chosen for the image, but would still be rigorously defined enough to make it a code golf.

Comment: @programmer5000 feel free to take this one. Are you thinking about doing code-golf somehow or a popularity contest?

Answer (score 4):

## Programming Puzzle or Code Golf?

(A judging books by covers question)

^Might need a better title.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

This question is based off the "Let's Judge Some Books By Their Covers" question.

Browsing the site, I see that 1859 of our 2692 questions (69%) are tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).  My question is: what's the difference?

Your goal is to write a program (or function) to predict, given only the title of a question, whether or not that question is tagged code-golf.  Your program will receive a title as input and should output either a truthy (if it's code golf) or falsey (it it's not) value.

Additionally, your program should contain no more than 1000 bytes.

### Scoring

The test data will be all of the questions on this website, excluding closed/migrated/deleted questions.  Your score will be the [Phi coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) calculated by comparing the results of your program with the actual data.  Higher values (closer to 1) are considered better.

The Phi coefficient is calculated via the following formula:

```
                actual
guess      puzzle  golf  total
  puzzle   A       B     Y
  golf     C       D     Z
  total    W       X

Phi = (AD - CB) / sqrt(WXYZ)
```

The benefit of this scoring method is that any form of random guessing (output not affected by input) results in an average score of zero.

The exact data set is yet to be generated.

### Notes

I believe this challenge is an improvement over the previous challenge due to a few reasons:

- The question title probably has a much stronger relationship to its tags than to votes, so there's hopefully more room for improvement and competition.
- Although there will be special-casing (for words like "short") it won't be for single questions.  There's no massive outliers in the data.

Comment: You might want to force the program to be deterministic to prevent `return rand<.69`

Comment: Please don't change the title, it's perfect :P

Comment: This has the issue of hardcoding. A near-perfect program can probably be written by compressing the 2692 bits needed into a 337-bytes magic string and using a hash table with enough expansion to make collisions rare. Ideally, you'd have a secret test set that's separate from the training set, but I don't know how to restrict that here except for "honor system" given that the data is public.

Answer (score 4):

## Score a Mahjong Hand

So you've built a solver for [which tiles you need to complete a Mahjong hand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/what-are-you-waiting-for-a-mahjong-solver), but you've heard that certain hands are worth more than others and sometimes a hand that scores too low can't even win.

So, you decide to build a program that will score hands for you.

This time, however, you will be making it for the full mahjong set. There are a total of 136 tiles in this variant, four copies of each of the following:

- 1 coin to 9 coins, represented from `1p` to `9p`.
- 1 stalk to 9 stalks, represented from `1s` to `9s`.
- 1 myriad to 9 myriads, represented from `1m` to `9m`.
- four winds, represented as `EE`, `SS`, `WW`, and `NN`.
- three dragon tiles, represented as `ZZ`, `FF`, and `BB`.

The winds and dragons are known as *honour* tiles, and they are not part of any suit.

A standard mahjong hand consists of four sets and a pair. A set can be any of:

- A *chow*, which is a sequence of three tiles in the same suit. Winds and dragon tiles cannot be part of a chow.
- A *pong*, which is a group of three of the same tile.
- A *kong*, which is a group of four of the same tile. Every kong increases the total number of tiles in a player's hand by 1.

Every chow and pong has three tiles in it, while a kong has four. So a winning hand can have anywhere from 14 to 18 tiles, depending on the number of kongs.

Now, the score that a hand has is based on *fan*. A valid winning hand has no *fan* by default. However, the following patterns count for *fan*:

#### Sets

- A pong or kong of dragons (e.g. `ZZ ZZ ZZ`): 1 fan
- A pong or kong of winds (e.g. `EE EE EE` or `SS SS SS SS`): 1 fan

#### Patterns

- A straight, 1-9 in a suit as three sets (e.g. `1s 2s 3s 4s 5s 6s 7s 8s 9s` + 1 more set and a pair): 3 fan
- A broken straight, 1-9 in a suit plus an additional 3, 5, and 7 (`1s 2s 3s 3s 4s 5s 5s 6s 7s 7s 8s 9s`): 5 fan
- A pong or kong of all three dragons (e.g. `ZZ ZZ ZZ FF FF FF BB BB BB BB`): 7 fan
- Four winds (`EE EE EE SS SS SS WW WW WW NN NN NN` + a pair): 10 fan
- Nine Gates (`1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9` of any single suit, plus one more of any tile in the suit): 14 fan (effectively 20 fan because of one-suit)

#### Entire hand patterns

- Entire hand is chows (e.g. `1s 2s 3s 6s 7s 8s 2p 3p 4p 7m 8m 9m NN NN`): 1 fan
- Entire hand is pongs or kongs (but not all kongs) (e.g. `1m 1m 1m 3s 3s 3s 7p 7p 7p NN NN NN EE EE`): 3 fan
- Entire hand is kongs only (e.g. `1m 1m 1m 1m 3s 3s 3s 3s 7p 7p 7p 7p NN NN NN NN EE EE`): 10 fan
- All tiles from one suit + honours (e.g `1p 1p 1p 4p 4p 4p 7p 8p 9p SS SS SS EE EE`): 3 fan
- All tiles from one suit (e.g. `1p 1p 1p 4p 4p 4p 7p 8p 9p 6p 6p 6p 5p 5p`): 6 fan
- All tiles honours (e.g `NN NN NN ZZ ZZ ZZ BB BB BB SS SS SS EE EE`): 9 fan

#### Special hands

The hands below are scored specially and do not follow the four-sets-and-a-pair rule.

- Seven Pairs (seven pairs of any tiles): 2 fan
- Seven pairs in the same suit: 10 fan
- Seven honour pairs: 20 fan
- Thirteen Orphans (`1p 9p 1s 9s 1m 9m EE SS WW NN ZZ FF BB` and one more of any of these 13): 10 fan

Note that you only have to account for the value of the hand itself - you don't need to care about what the prevailing wind is or whether the tile was self-drawn, by discard, or anything else.

Also note that a hand may fulfill multiple criteria. If it does, add up all the *fan* from each criterion it fulfills, except if the hand is a special hand.

Comment: I won't be around for long. But sure, if you can make a chatroom and link to it here, I'll check in on it periodically.

Comment: Chat link: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19601/score-a-mahjong-hand-discussion)

Comment: Oh, just using that one? It might get muddled up in the rest of the messages, though.

Comment: Some ambiguous case that never happens in a real game: `111122233345555`, which can be either `1111 222 33 345 555` or `11 123 123 234 5555`. Both are 6 fan, though. Btw: `psm` are Japanese and `ZFB` are Chinese. Shouldn't that be at least consistent? (Or is that the standard somewhere?)

Comment: @user23013 In my question I was using Japanese, just so I could plug tests into [Tenhou](http://tenhou.net/2/)'s solver. They use `1z2z3z...` for honours. `ZFB` is indeed Chinese, but unfortunately taking the initials for Japanese gives `CHH`. I'm not sure if there's a standard anywhere.

Comment: @Sp3000 In fact it would be `HHC` in the Japanese order... I think most Japanese people don't use letters for honors. And Chinese people don't use letters at all. I did some search and found some English-speaking people are just using something worse: Red, Green, ...

Comment: `ZFB` is Chinese, and `psm` was Japanese/Cantonese but there I was just following the convention from the previous question. I can change it to `BSW` if you want, though.

Comment: I was just nitpicking... never mind.

Comment: The multiple maching criteria should be clarified: For example seven pairs in the same suit, scores just 10 total - not 12. In otherwords, it isn't considered to match both "Seven Pairs" and "Seven Pairs in the same suit".

Answer (score 4):

## Invert the matrix

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

*The name says it all. I am surprised that there is no preexisting question on calculating matrix inversion*

Given an `n`X`n` invertible matrix, your task is to output its inverse.

## Rules

- Floating point precision of at least 3 significant decimal places is required
- You can assume that the input matrix will always have an inverse
- You cannot use any inbuilt methods (or external libraries) to perform any of the following tasks:

  - Calculate the inverse
  - Solve system of equations
  - Calculate determinant
  - Multiply two matrices or calculate dot product.
- In other words, your code has to calculate the inverse using any of the mathematical methods itself. (If I missed out any inbuilt methods in the above rule, this rule should make it clear that it cannot be used)
- You cannot calculate inverse by randomly generate random matrix and then multiply with the input to check for unit matrix.

## Input

Input can be in a format of your choice. For example:

```
[[ 1, 3, 4],
 [ 5, 7, 8],
 [ 3, 4, 5]]
```

or

```
1 3 4
5 7 8
3 4 5
```

etc

## Output

The output should be in the same format as the input, except for 1 requirement that each row of the matrix should be in a separate line with elements of the same row on the same line.

This is code-golf so shortest code in bytes win.

## Sandbox notes

What do you think of the problem ? Too mundane ? Too trivial ? Need any extra rule to make it more interesting ?

Comment: There *is* a [pre-existing question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12412/194), although it only covers 2x2.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, also, it is based on system of equations, which is related but not exactly same as Inverse (Inverse is a part of solving equations). So size plus this fact should make this question different enough ?

Comment: "Floating point precision upto 3 decimal places is required" - did you mean "Floating point precision of at least 3 decimal places is required"?

Comment: @JanDvorak err.

Comment: The whole business of numerical accuracy is a minefield for this because there are many ill-conditioned instances. You can't talk in terms of decimal places unless you either require people to work in arbitrary precision or guarantee some very conservative bounds on the input and output values. (Unless you want to merely go for conservative bounds and include some test cases which will disqualify naïve Gaussian elimination and force people to do a Bareiss-style approach, but that will lead to having not more than one or two correct answers and probably a dozen incorrect ones).

Comment: To get around thorny questions of ill-conditioned matrices and the possibility of divide-by-zero, how about only requiring that the algorithm work with high probability on random Gaussian matrices of size at most 100?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I might not have understood even 10% of that comment. Can you please tell me what can I put in place of that rule then ?

Comment: @xnor what do you mean by ill-conditioned matrices ?

Comment: No, I can't. I don't consider myself qualified to write a spec for inverting matrices. I know what the problem *is*, but I don't understand it well enough to formulate validity constraints. I think it would be best to leave the idea for someone who has a firm grasp of the numerical analysis of linear algebra to pick up and finish.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I disagree with you. The purpose of this challenge is not to get an mathematically perfect matrix inversion code, but instead, a code that calculates the inverse in the shortest and smartest way. Martin suggested in chat that the floating point precision upto certain significant digits can be made a compulsion till a matrix size of say 10. Simply hoping to get a mathematically experienced person who has mastery in matrix inversion to pick up the challenge is a very pessimistic approach.

Comment: @Optimizer Here's the issue: say I write a row reduction algorithm. I want to subtract a multiple of the first row from the second in order to zero out the first entry of the second row. Do I have to consider the case where the first entry of the first row is zero, so I get a divide-by-zero error? Ok, say I have a separate check if equals 0. What if that entry is supposed to be 0, but as a result of a previous calculation is 0.00000001, failing the check? Now my second row is ginormous and it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Optimizer Alternatively, finding the inverse mod 2 would avoid accuracy issues.

Comment: @xnor mod 2 as in ?

Answer (score 4):

## Responsible governance [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### Background

For years, the Federal government of the United States has been in chaos. The Presidency and Congress are under different parties, and there are no compromises in sight. Instead of passing a budget or improving the tax code, the politicians are squabbling as the country teeters on the brink of economic collapse. It seems that a few more years of political dysfunction will soon reduce the United States to rubble.

Yet, some have noticed that many state governments seem to be functioning. Taxes are being reformed, education is being improved, and even compromise can be found on occasion!

The solution is clear. The federal government must be dissolved. Each state will control its own eduction, infrastructure, and healthcare, but the budgets will be pooled. As the governor of your state, you must use the country's funds to improve your constituents' lives, but also be frugal enough to let your neighbors prosper as well.

### Rules

This system of government will be in place for 10 years (120 months), after which the results of this experiment will be analyzed. Each month, every governor will be given the opportunity to use the country's funds to pay for one project of their choice.

The government starts with $1,000,000 in the bank, times the number of states. In every state, life expectancy is 75 years, education is at 95 IQ, and the infrastructure gets a rating of 65 points.

Every year, the following happens:

- First, taxes are collected and centralized expenses are paid.
- For each of the next twelve months:

  - Each governor, in order, is allowed to finance a project.
- Finally, information about each states' education, healthcare, and infrastructure is updated to reflect the projects built.

### Scoring

The final score is the government's total funds, times average state's life expectancy, times the average state's IQ, times the average state's infrastructure rating. (These averages are not weighted by population.)

This entire experiment will be performed many times. Each time, a different governor will be excluded. The winner will be the governor such that the final score is the *worst* when they are excluded, since they must have had the biggest impact on the government's success.

### Details

- *N* is the number of governors (not counting the excluded one)
- *L* is the life expectancy of a particular state.
- *L*<sub>a</sub> is the average life expectancy.
- *E* is the IQ of a particular state.
- *E*<sub>a</sub> is the average IQ.
- *T* is the infrastructure rating of a particular state.
- *T*<sub>a</sub> is the average infrastructure rating.

  #### Revenues and expenses
- Annual revenue: $ *N* *E*<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> *T*<sub>a</sub>
- Annual expenses: $10,000,000,000,000 *N* / *L*<sub>a</sub><sup>3</sup> / *T*<sub>a</sub>

  #### Projects
- Each of the three factors (health, education, and infrastructure) is calculated on a state-by-state basis. *L* starts at 75, *E* starts at 95, and *T* starts at 65.
- For each factor, the bonuses are cumulative.
- For example, the bonuses `L +2`, `L +5` mean that *L* = ( 75 + 2 + 5 ) = 82.
- Each project can be done only once by each state.
- Each project has an associated six-letter code (for I/O).

  #### List of projects
- [ENOUGH] Enough medicine: *L* +5, cost: $300,000
- [CANSCR] Early cancer screenings: *L* + 4, cost $200,000
- [FREECC] Free community college: *E* +10, cost: $400,000
- [LIBRAR] Library system: *E* + 3, cost: $150,000
- [MUSEUM] Museums *E* + 1 *in each state*, cost: $500,000

***many more in the actual challenge...***

#### Your program

Write a function in Java, Python 2, or Ruby, which accepts an integer (the government's funds) and returns an optional six-letter code, corresponding to the project chosen. If nothing is returned, or the returned value is invalid, or the chosen project was already built by you, or costs more than the government's funds, no project will be built for this month.

You may not use any I/O, except for one file called "`<program-name>.txt`, which you may use however you wish, provided it's kept under 2 megabytes at all times.

---

Some questions:

1. Are the rules completely clear?
2. Are there any perverse incentives? The goal should be to improve one's own state while being frugal with the government's funds.
3. In the first section too political?
4. Is the challenge too complicated?

Comment: I wonder about the formulas used for score/revenue/expenses. Have you run this a few times with dummy states to see if it works in practice? I'd hate to see a [simple, constant choice resulting in a clear winner](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44781/14215) with no good way to stop it.

Comment: That's a good point; thanks for the feedback. The existing formulas are sort of placeholders for now. Once the other details are worked out, then I'll focus on getting the formulas balanced.

Answer (score 4):

## Real-Time Hovercraft Battle

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Hovercrafts are cool.  Hovercrafts with rail guns are even cooler.  In this challenge, you will write a program to controller a battling hovercraft.

The hovercrafts in this game obey the laws of physics.  A hovercraft with no acceleration will continue moving in a straight line.  Also, a spinning hovercraft will continue to spin.

At each moment in time, the hovercraft's motion is defined by a few variables: the location, angle, linear velocity, and angular velocity of the hovercraft.

Hovercrafts are circles of radius 4, with a clear "front" and "back" end.  On the left and right there are two forward-facing fans which serve as propulsion.  Each fan has 8 power settings, from -3 to +4.  These fans control additional aspects of the hovercraft's motion, the linear and angular acceleration.

Todo: determine the mass and moment of inertia for the hovercraft, which will then allow me to determine which power settings have which effects.

The real fun begins with the rail gun.  The rail gun fires from the front of the hovercraft and deals damage when it strikes the side of the opposing hovercraft.  The ammunition travels at a fast speed but finite, and the angle of the shot depends on the motion of the hovercraft.  Firing the railgun also produces a recoil effect.

Note:  I need to prevent the "rotating turret" strategy: spin really fast and fire when you find yourself pointed at something.  An a truly instantaneous shot would never miss in this circumstance.

In order to power the rail gun, you must first charge a capacitor.  Capacitor charging can be turned on and off.  When the capacitor is charging, the fans will have reduced thrust. Once the capacitor stops charging (either it is full or charging is turned off) the thrusters will act normally again.  You can still fire the rail gun when the capacitor is charging: the shot will have reduced damage.  By default, the capacitor starts empty with charging on.

## The Tournament

All of the participants will participate in a series of 1v1v1v1 battles.  The goal is to survive the longest.

The battle arena is a radius 400 circle.  Hovercraft can collide with the boundary, bounce,and take a little damage.  At the start of the match, one hovercraft will be randomly located (1 per quadrant).

The finish order for a round will be determined by the order of death.  After a certain period of time, all remaining hovercrafts will be deemed co-champions of that round.

After a decent number of battles (a number not currently determined, but something less than an exhaustive search but enough to determine the overall winner with non-negative confidence), the finish orders for each battle will be treated as ballots in a form of ranked voting scheme.  By using a mathematically sound voting scheme, the final order should represent the results of the battles pretty well.

### I have not started the controller yet.

This will be a real-time game.  Each hovercraft program can request updates and send commands in real-time.  This means that game ticks can happen while your program is running, and each game tick is a very small increment of time (as fast as feasible).

Comment: Check out [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/). It is a long-running contest with comparable rules. What vision do the players have? Can you see the orientation of other participants?

Answer (score 4):

## Best Approximating Polynomial

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) ([higher-order-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-function)?)

Let *f*(*x*) and *g*(*x*) be two continuous real-valued functions over the interval [*a*, *b*], where *a* < *b*. 
The **mean squared error** (or simply "**error**" hereafter) between *f*(*x*) and *g*(*x*) is defined as

[image: Equation 1]

Roughly speaking, the smaller the error is, the closer *f*(*x*) and *g*(*x*) are.

In this challenge, *f*(*x*) will be some user-supplied target function and *g*(*x*) will be a polynomial of some maximal degree *n*. 
The goal is to find the polynomial *g*(*x*) that minimizes the error w.r.t. *f*(*x*) (such a polynomial exists and is unique;)
we say that *g*(*x*) is the **best approximation** of *f*(*x*) over the interval [*a*, *b*] using a polynomial of degree at most *n*.

For example, let's take the function *f*(*x*) = cos *x* over the interval [0, ½*π*] (which contains all the "interesting" information about this function), and look for a polynomial of degree at most 2.
As you might know, the Taylor expansion of cos *x* up to degree 2 is *t*(*x*) = 1 - ½*x*<sup>2</sup>. 
The error between *t*(*x*) and *f*(*x*) is approximately 6.25×10<sup>-3</sup>. 
We can do better than that!
If I got my math right, the best approximation of cos *x* over the interval [0, ½*π*] using a polynomial of degree at most 2 is (brace yourselves):

[image: Equation 2]

or approximately *g*(*x*) ≈ -0.34 *x*<sup>2</sup> - 0.13 *x* + 1.02. 
The error between *g*(*x*) and *f*(*x*) is approximately 7.03×10<sup>-5</sup>—two orders of magnitude better!
The difference is very notable, as the following plot shows:

[image: Plot 1]

### Challenge

Write a **program** or a **function** that takes a function *f*(*x*), an interval [*a*, *b*], where *a* < *b*, and a nonnegative integer *n*, and returns the polynomial of degree at most *n* that best approximates *f*(*x*) over the given interval.

### Input

You may read the input through **STDIN**, the **command line**, as **function arguments** or an **equivalent method**.
Note that you don't have to accept *a*, *b* and *n* in any specific format; particularly, you don't have to read *a* and *b* as `[a, b]`.

You should accept the function *f*(*x*) in one of the following forms:

- As a language-level **function**, **function-like object**, **polymorphic object** or any other **equivalent method** your language uses to communicate functions.
- As a **string** containing an expression.
  The actual format of the string is flexible, but it should be expressive enough to allow basic arithmetic operations, exponentiation, and preferably also logarithms and basic trigonometric functions.
  The intention is for it to be used with something like `eval`.
  Note that you're allowed to require the string to be formatted in some convenient way (within reason), for example, pre-wrapped in a function
  (as in `"function (x) { return x + Math.sin(x); }"`).
- If, and only if, both of the above methods are impractical in your language, you may not take the function as input and assume that **the function is already defined** by the user.
  In this case, add to your score a **+16<sub>byte</sub> penalty**.

You may assume that the input is valid.

Please specify how your program accepts its input in your post.

### Output

You may write the output to **STDOUT**, return it as the **function's result** or use an **equivalent method**.
You may express the polynomial as a **list of coefficients** (e.g., `[1, -2, 1]`), using some **pretty-printed** form (e.g., `x^2 - 2x + 1`) or some other **equivalent method**.
Either way, it should be easy to determine the coefficients of the different terms from your output; so, for example, you may not return the polynomial as an opaque function.

Note that unlike the example given at the beginning of the post, you don't have to produce symbolic output (unless you want to); a numeric output is fine.

Please specify how your program returns its output in your post.
If the order of the coefficients may be ambiguous, make sure to clarify it.

### Accuracy and Run Time

The numerical accuracy of your program is most likely going to be dependent on the target function, the degree of the polynomial and the amount of time you allow it to run.
As a result, giving a general accuracy requirement is impractical.
However, your program should process each of the below **test cases** in **less than a minute** and produce a polynomial whose error w.r.t. the target function is **no worse** than the **error specified in the test case**.

### Additional Rules

- You may not use any function that performs this specific task.

### Scoring

This is code-golf.
The **shortest code**, in bytes, wins.

### Test Cases

Recall that your program should complete each of the following test cases in less than a minute, with an error that is less than or equal to the specified error.
That being said, this is not a hard and fast rule; if your program struggles with a couple of test cases, that's fine.
Note that the approximating polynomials listed in the test cases are just an approximation and are only given for illustration.
Although theoretically each case has a unique optimal polynomial, your program might produce a notably different one; this is especially true for the higher degree polynomials.
However, both polynomials should behave similarly over the given interval, which is why the correctness of your program is determined by the error.
Likewise, the errors listed in the test cases are only an approximation and are not necessarily the errors of the corresponding listed polynomials—they're just a lower-bound for accuracy.

```html
Test 1
f(x) = sin(x)
From: -pi
To: pi
Max. Deg.: 0
g(x) = 0
e^2 = 5.0001 * 10^-1

Test 2
f(x) = sin(x)
From: -pi
To: pi
Max. Deg.: 1
g(x) = 0.304 x
e^2 = 1.9604 * 10^-1

Test 3
f(x) = cos(x)
From: -pi
To: pi
Max. Deg.: 2
g(x) = -0.231 x^2 + 0.76
e^2 = 3.8032 * 10^-2

Test 4
f(x) = sin(x)
From: -pi
To: pi
Max. Deg.: 5
g(x) = 0.005643 x^5 - 0.155 x^3 + 0.988 x
e^2 = 1.8490 * 10^-5

Test 5
f(x) = cos(x)
From: 0
To: 3pi
Max. Deg.: 8
g(x) = 6.69465*10^-9 x^8 - 1.01005*10^-4 x^7 + 0.00332742 x^6 - 0.0400508 x^5 + 0.205029 x^4 - 0.351657 x^3 - 0.120773 x^2 - 0.169562 x + 1.01830
e^2 = 1.9764 * 10^-5

Test 6
f(x) = e^(-x^2)
From: -2
To: 2
Max. Deg.: 10
g(x) = -0.00143879 x^10 + 0.0211686 x^8 - 0.133468 x^6 + 0.473915 x^4 - 0.992265 x^2 + 0.999624
e^2 = 8.4405 * 10^-8

Test 7
f(x) = 1/(x^2 + 1)
From: -3
To: 3
Max. Deg.: 16
g(x) = 3.16504*10^-6 x^16 - 1.23974*10^-4 x^14 + 0.00203230 x^12 - 0.0181511 x^10 + 0.0966544 x^8 - 0.318123 x^6 + 0.662508 x^4 - 0.923653 x^2 + 0.996846
e^2 = 2.6 * 10^-6

Test 8
f(x) = e^((sin(x))^3)
From: 0
To: 2pi
Max. Deg.: 1
g(x) = -0.224 x + 1.87
e^2 = 2.6845 * 10^-1

Test 9
f(x) = (cos(x))^5
From: pi
To: 2pi
Max. Deg.: 17
g(x) = 6.31854*10^-12 x^17 - 1.63320*10^-11 x^16 - 2.78192*10^-10 x^15 - 8.73964*10^-10 x^14 - 2.74564*10^-9 x^13 + 5.59537*10^-8 x^12 - 2.70984*10^-8 x^11 - 2.61779*10^-5 x^10 - 2.67450*10^-7 x^9 - 8.40220*10^-7 x^8 + 0.3247516 x^7 - 7.3046333 x^6 + 72.908485 x^5 - 408.43197 x^4 + 1362.34294 x^3 - 2657.0269 x^2 + 2737.319113682029 x - 1100.1514
e^2 = 5.8 * 10^-5

Test 10
f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2)
From: -1
To: 1
Max. Deg.: 20
g(x) = -627.601 x^20 + 2853.92 x^18 - 5499.47 x^16 + 5845.71 x^14 - 3738.80 x^12 + 1472.42 x^10 - 350.970 x^8 + 47.6426 x^6 - 3.39128 x^4 - 0.414096 x^2 + 0.999632
e^2 = 1.2 * 10^-6

Test 11
f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2) + 0.1*sin(4*pi*x)
From: -1
To: 1
Max. Deg.: 18
g(x) = -203.563 x^18 + 141.013 x^17 + 821.952 x^16 - 757.063 x^15 - 1378.59 x^14 + 1771.07 x^13 + 1241.44 x^12 - 2345.58 x^11 - 648.127 x^10 + 1895.10 x^9 + 197.425 x^8 - 928.025 x^7 - 33.5970 x^6 + 254.982 x^5 + 2.70132 x^4 - 32.7510 x^3 - 0.590680 x^2 + 1.25167 x + 1.00047
e^2 = 1.9 * 10^-6

Test 12
f(x) = abs(x)
From: -1
To: 1
Max. Deg.: 6
g(x) = 1.46667 x^6 - 2.82024 x^4 + 2.30724 x^2 + 0.0854450
e^2 = 5.08635 * 10^-4

Test 13
f(x) = x*sin(x^1.2) + 10*sqrt(x)
From: 0
To: 2.5pi
Max. Deg.: 3
g(x) = -0.129 x^3 + 1.046 x^2 + 1.392 x + 6.98
e^2 = 7.3389 * 10^0

Test 14
f(x) = sin(log(1 + e^cos(x)))
From: 2
To: 10
Max. Deg.: 10
g(x) = 9.52190*10^-10 x^10 - 6.30342*10^-6 x^9 + 3.3746525*10^-4 x^8 - 0.0078575036 x^7 + 0.103708803 x^6 - 0.84926923 x^5 + 4.4421097 x^4 - 14.766225 x^3 + 30.153933 x^2 - 34.72483 x + 17.8389
e^2 = 5.4 * 10^-5

Test 15
f(x) = abs(log(x))
From: 1/e
To: e
Max. Deg.: 15
g(x) = 6.07034*10^-8 x^15 + 9.85444*10^-5 x^14 + 3.35349*10^-7 x^13 + 7.88206*10^-7 x^12 + 1.85260*10^-6 x^11 + 4.35436*10^-6 x^10 - 3.4245574 x^9 + 42.093925 x^8 - 228.714688 x^7 + 711.8547 x^6 - 1383.06 x^5 + 1720.8859 x^4 - 1357.596 x^3 + 651.1596 x^2 - 173.8175 x + 20.680
e^2 = 1.587 * 10^-4
```

### Test Program

The following snippet can be used to compute the best approximating polynomial for a given function, as well as to calculate the error of your own approximations.
Note that it has limited accuracy, and becomes numerically unstable for polynomials of degree over 20–30.

```html
<style>#main {display: none;}#status_container {padding: 4px;}#status {padding: 5px;background-color: #fffdce;box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 3.5px #aaaaaa;font-size: 10pt;word-wrap: break-word;display: none;}#status[loading] {display: inline;}</style><span id="main"><table id="main_table"><tr><td><div id="plot_area"><div id="plot_float"><div id="plot_container"><div id="plot"></div></div></div></div></td><td><table class="field_table" id="field_table"><tr><td class="field_name">()&nbsp;=</td><td><table class="padding_table"><tr><td><div class="input_container"><div class="input_underlay" id="expression0_underlay"></div><div class="input_error_underlay" id="expression0_error_underlay"></div><textarea class="input" id="expression0" spellcheck="false" oninput="update(0)">e^-(x/6) cos x</textarea></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><table class="horz_field_table"><tr><td><table class="field_table"><tr><td class="field_name small_field_name">From</td><td><table><tr><td><div class="input_container"><div class="input_underlay" id="from_underlay"></div><div class="input_error_underlay" id="from_error_underlay"></div><textarea class="input" id="from" spellcheck="false" oninput="update()">0</textarea></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td><table class="field_table"><tr><td class="field_name small_field_name">To</td><td><table><tr><td><div class="input_container"><div class="input_underlay" id="to_underlay"></div><div class="input_error_underlay" id="to_error_underlay"></div><textarea class="input" id="to" spellcheck="false" oninput="update()">2.5pi</textarea></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td><table class="field_table"><tr><td class="field_name small_field_name">Max.&nbsp;Deg.</td><td><table><tr><td><div class="input_container"><div class="input_underlay" id="max_deg_underlay"></div><div class="input_error_underlay" id="max_deg_error_underlay"></div><textarea class="input" id="max_deg" spellcheck="false" oninput="max_deg_add(0)" onkeydown="return spinner_keydown(event, 'max_deg', max_deg_add)">3</textarea></div></td></tr></table></td><td><div class="button_group small_button_group"><table><tr><td><button class="increment pos_button fixed_button" id="max_deg_inc" title="Increment" onclick="max_deg_add(+1)">▲</button></td></tr><tr><td><button class="decrement neg_button fixed_button" id="max_deg_dec" title="Decrement" onclick="max_deg_add(-1)">▼</button></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></td><td class="separator"></td><td><div class="button_group"><button class="check_button" id="hold" title="Supress update" onclick="hold()">Hold</button></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr class="separated_row" id="expression0_0"><td class="field_name">()&nbsp;=</td><td><table class="padding_table"><tr><td><div class="output_container"><div class="output polynomial" id="poly"></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id="expression0_1"><td class="field_name"><span class="variable">ϵ</span><sup>2</sup>&nbsp;=</td><td><table class="horz_field_table"><tr><td><div class="output_container"><div class="output" id="poly_error"><table class="horz_field_table"><tr><td class="error_value" id="poly_error_value"></td><td class="error_change" id="poly_error_change"></td></tr></table></div></div></td><td><div class="button_group"><button class="add_expr pos_button fixed_button" id="add_expr0" title="Add function" onclick="add_expr(0, event.ctrlKey + 2 * event.shiftKey)">+</button><button class="remove_expr neg_button fixed_button" style="display: none;" id="remove_expr0" title="Remove function" onclick="remove_expr(0, event.ctrlKey)" disabled>-</button></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr class="options separated_row" id="flag_row"><td colspan="2"><table class="horz_flag_table"><tr><td><label class="flag_container" title="Plot legend"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="flag" id="legend" onchange="update(null, true)" checked></td><td>Key</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label class="flag_container" title="Extra accuracy"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="flag" id="extra_accuracy" onchange="update(undefined, true)"></td><td>Acc.</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label class="flag_container" title="Scientific notation"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="flag" id="scientific_notation" onchange="render_output()"></td><td>Sci.</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label class="flag_container" title="Decimal exponent style"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="flag" id="decimal_exponent" onchange="render_output()"></td><td>Dec.</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label class="flag_container" title="Ascending order"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="flag" id="poly_ascending" onchange="render_output()"></td><td>Asc.</td></tr></table></label></td><td><select id="poly_mode" title="Polynomial style" onchange="render_output()"><option value="disp">Display</option><option value="text">Text</option><option value="prog">Program</option><option value="list">List</option></select></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></span><div id="status_container"><span id="status" loading>Loading...</span></div><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gist.githack.com/anonymous/6059e31443745ba122dd/raw/9ca2667d0027fc4c4764533098885a8c0cc31674/poly.css"><!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]--><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script><script async type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.githack.com/anonymous/6059e31443745ba122dd/raw/aa24abd74de60be00eb3d5b4cbb4e39ee8cbf3d6/poly.js"></script>
```

### Sandbox Notes

The "no functions that perform this specific task" rule seems to be too ambiguous after all.
I'm returning this to the sandbox for now.

Comment: Challenge or not, your code snippet is a mighty useful tool for math impaired people like me :).

Comment: "*You may not use any function that performs this specific task.*" But functions which perform symbolic integration, enumerate families of orthogonal polynomials, or solve systems of linear equations are ok?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm still mulling it over. I tried coming up with a list of no-no functions but it ended up too long. I'm aware that with the current spec Mathematica folks are going to have a field day :)

Comment: Is it allowed to examine the function in ways other than numerically evaluating it?

Comment: @feersum Assuming you mean something like inspecting the string or doing some symbolic analysis, then yes, that's ok. Like I said to Peter, though, I _might_ disallow some _builtin_ functions, like integration (symbolic or otherwise).

Answer (score 4):

## Find a Diagonal

Given a (possibly concave) polygon of `n ≥ 4` sides, output a valid *diagonal*, a line segment joining two distinct vertices which, aside from the endpoints, is completely contained within the interior of the polygon.

For example, for the polygon

```
[(0, 0), (3, 0), (1, 1), (0, 4)]
```

a valid diagonal (in fact, the only possible diagonal) is:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

[image: Diagonal]

Some invalid diagonals are:

```
[(3, 0), (0, 4)]     Lies outside the polygon
[(0, 0), (3, 0)]     Is an edge of the polygon - the interior of the line is not inside
[(0, 0), (0, 0)]     Two identical vertices
```

### Input/output

Input will be `n` pairs of integers representing the vertices of the polygon in order. There is no fixed orientation for the input — it could be clockwise or anticlockwise. You may write either a function or a full program for this challenge, and assume any clear (all integers distinguishable) and convenient list/string format for the input.

You may assume that no three *consecutive* vertices of the polygon are collinear, i.e. there are no 180 degree angles. You may also assume that all coordinates are between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Output will be 2 pairs of integers representing a diagonal, which may also be in any clear and convenient list/string format.

### Rules

- You must work in the integers or rationals. In particular, you **cannot** use floating point integers, due to imprecision.
- You may not use any polygon-related builtins.
- This is code-golf, so the program in the fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

For each case, the first line is the input polygon, and the second line is all possible edges which are a valid diagonal. You only need to output **one** valid diagonal, and the vertices may be in either order.

```
Vertical diagonal
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, 3)]
[(1, 1), (1, 3)]

Horizontal diagonal
[(5, 0), (3, 4), (8, 8), (6, 4)]
[(3, 4), (6, 4)]
```

The relevant images are given below, in test case order (click the thumbnails to view).

[image: Test 1]
[image: Test 2]

*(More cases to be added)*

Comment: Your first example of a valid diagonal has one end-point which isn't actually a vertex of the polygon. The example would benefit from an image. Since you're restricting people to exact arithmetic, you should specify a bound on the vertex coordinate values so that people can work out whether they're at risk of overflow.

Answer (score 4):

## Flit - a simple board game for bots

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

I've made a [human playable version of this game](https://trichoplax.github.io/flit/) with a simple strategy to give an idea of how the game plays out. You can play it before or after reading the rules here - picking up the rules intuitively adds an extra challenge...

If playing this gives any idea about whether the KotH version would be better with 2, 4, or more players per game, or any other subtle adjustments that would help, please let me know.

---

> Note: adjacency is vertical or horizontal - for this game there are no diagonal neighbours.

### Overview

The board is a square grid. Each bot starts with 2 pieces of their colour, and gains more pieces by converting neutral pieces that appear from time to time. The objective is to end up with more pieces than your opponents.

Each turn, one bot moves. It chooses one of its pieces and moves it to be next to another of its pieces. There is no limit to the distance a piece can move in a single step, provided it lands next to a piece of the same colour.

#### Neutral pieces

There are initially zero neutral pieces.

A new neutral piece can appear at any time, regardless of whether there are already neutral pieces unconverted. A neutral piece will only appear on an empty square that has 4 empty neighbours, to prevent it being instantly converted.

If a neutral piece is adjacent to another piece, it is converted - it becomes the colour of that piece. A neutral piece can only ever be adjacent to a single other piece - it will be instantly converted before any other bot has a chance to move next to it.

#### Moving

A move is specified by an origin square and a destination square. It is a valid move if the origin square contains a piece of the bot's colour, and the destination square is empty and is adjacent to at least one piece of the bot's colour. Note that the piece being moved cannot also be the piece adjacent to the destination square (a piece cannot simply move next to its own previous position). Two distinct pieces are required - one to be moved, and one to be adjacent to the destination.

**[Not moving is a valid move, and is indicated by specifying the same coordinates for origin square and destination square. *not sure about this rule*]** Not supplying a move within the time limit also results in not moving, but repeatedly exceeding the time limit will lead to the bot losing the opportunity to make further moves.

#### Communication

The board information will not be supplied each turn. Instead the bot must keep track of the board state itself. Each time a change is made a message will be sent to all bots describing the change. If a bot chooses not to move, the non-move will not be broadcast.

The board starts empty. The initial two pieces for each bot will be broadcast to all bots, then the first bot will be sent a request for a move, to which it must respond within the time limit. Any response sent after the time limit expires will be discarded (any waiting input will be read and discarded before the next request for a move is sent to that bot).

Bots will therefore have complete information about the board state at all times.

> ## Specification
>
> **Available**: An **available** square is an empty square that has 4 empty neighbours
>
> #### Players
>
> There are 4 bots competing in each game. Bots are numbered 1 to 4 and take turns in that fixed order.
>
> #### Board
>
> The board is a 32 by 32 square grid. It wraps toroidally - every square has 4 neighbours. The board has no boundaries - no edges or corners to give an advantage.
>
> #### Initial state
>
> For each bot, one piece will be placed on a square chosen uniformly from the **available** squares. After all first
> pieces have been placed, a second piece will be placed for each bot in
> the same way. The initial state contains no neutral pieces.
>
> #### Addition of neutral pieces
>
> Each turn one bot will move. After that move has been made, the addition of a new neutral piece will be considered. A square will be selected at random. If that square is **available** then a neutral piece will be placed on it with probability 1/16. If the square is unavailable then play continues - a second square will not be selected. **[This differs from the human playable version linked above: there a list is kept of all available squares and a neutral piece is placed on one of those with probability 1/6 each turn - I now prefer this approach so the rate of new neutral pieces does not slow in the end game]**
>
> #### Bot STDIN
>
> All received messages will be terminated by a newline.
> Each bot will receive messages of two types: an update or a move request
>
> **Update:**
>
> x y c
>
> where (x, y) is the square to be updated, and c is the new colour (which may be 0 for empty, 1, 2, 3 or 4 for a bot colour, or 5 for neutral).
>
> **Move request:**
>
> M
>
> where M is the literal string "M" and indicates that a move is required.
>
> #### Bot STDOUT
>
> The response must be terminated by a newline.
> A bot responds with a move in the following format:
>
> x0 y0 x1 y1
>
> where (x0, y0) is the origin square, and (x1, y1) is the destination square.
>
> If origin and destination are identical, no move will be made. This is valid and does not lead to the bot being penalised. The bot will only be penalised if it fails to respond within the time limit.
>
> #### Time limit
>
> The time limit is 50ms. If a bot exceeds the time limit on 5 consecutive turns then it will no longer be prompted for moves. That bot will be frozen for the rest of the game.
>
> #### Winning criterion
>
> The winner is the bot with the most pieces when the game ends. There is no reward for second place. If two bots tie for first place, neither is rewarded.
>
> The game ends when one of the following conditions is met:
>
> - the total number of turns taken exceeds 32,768 (8,192 per bot)
> - all 4 bots choose not to move consecutively
> - one bot has too many pieces to catch up with
>
> Too many pieces to catch up with is defined as follows:
>
> - A, B and C are the numbers of pieces of the other 3 bots.
> - D is the number of pieces of the bot in question.
> - N is the number of neutral pieces.
> - E is the number of empty squares.
> - P is the number of potential neutral pieces. P = N + E - 4
> - M is the maximum number of pieces attainable by A, B or C.
> - M = Max(A+P, B+P, C+P)
> - If D > M then the bot has too many pieces to catch up with.

I've tried to make this game as simple as possible, while still having non-trivial dynamics.

Comment: Time limit could be abused - the bot is allowed to just take its sweet time for 4 turns straight, followed by a reset... How about average time?

Comment: Ah good point. I'll probably go with average time per move after an arbitrary 10 seconds to allow for high variance early on.

Comment: First player is at a *very* slight, systemic disadvantage. He's the only one that *cannot* see a neutral piece on his first turn. Piece spawning should probably happen *before* each player makes a move, instead of after.

Comment: Oh good point. That small difference is definitely relevant. Neutral pieces before rather than after a move sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

## The Predator of my Predator is my Prey

#### (Three Team KotH)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Three teams: Red, Green, Blue

- Red kills Green
- Green kills Blue
- Blue kills Red

As in [Red vs Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots), each entrant is assigned a colour based on their userid. Your objective is to ensure your team has the most surviving members at the end of the game.

The rules are simple but the dynamics may not be obvious. For example, wiping out your prey colour early on seems like success, but it leaves your predator colour with no predators of their own, and free to wipe you out. This means early on it may be better to herd your prey rather than kill them, but this could back-fire if your team leaves it too late...

### Possible game styles

Whatever the style, when a Red bot touches a Green bot, the Green bot becomes a Red bot (the bot's code is replaced by its attacker's code). The total number of bots is therefore constant throughout the game. There are a number of settings in which such a game could be played:

- pixels in an open arena (like Red vs Blue)
- pixels in an arena with obstacles/walls/mazes
- bots in a continuous arena (no grid), free to turn smoothly through 360 degrees

I like the idea of a continuous arena, and bots only seeing a small radius semi-disc ahead of them. With no vision behind them they would have to either turn regularly, or coordinate with their team mates to get more information on their surroundings. Bots would be able to write messages and read the messages of other bots on the same team.

---

## Sandbox questions

- Stack Snippet / full multi-language KotH?
- which of the game styles suggested would be most interesting?

Answer (score 4):

## ASCII Art of the Day Series

My new found love for ASCII art has lead me to a lot of good (trivial and non-trivial) ideas for ASCII ART challenges. Here are the ideas :

[***1. Double Knot***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50484/draw-an-ascii-double-knot)

[***2. Flow Snakes***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50521/31414)

[***3. Chinese Shrine***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50625/ascii-art-of-the-day-3-chinese-shrines)

[***4. Zodiac Signs***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51123/31414)

---

***6. Snow Flakes***

Its time for another ASCII Art of the Day. This time, we are going back to the winters and drawing Snow Flakes (not to be mixed up with [Flow Snakes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50521/31414) ;) ). The snow flakes are generative based on random walk so each run should give a different pretty snow flake ASCII.

## Challenge

Given an input integer `N`, draw an ASCII snow flake of radius `N` using the construction instructions provided below.

## Construction

The Snow Flake will have 6-fold rotational symmetry and 3-fold reflection symmetry. You will ideally only generate 1 out of the 12 wedges in a snow flake and then rotate/mirror them to get the other wedges.

Lets consider the following snow flake for `N = 5`:

```
     \__    __/
     /_/ /\ \_\
    __ \ \/ / __
    \_\_\/\/_/_/
__/\___\_\/_/___/\__
  \/ __/_/\_\__ \/
    /_/ /\/\ \_\
     __/ /\ \__
     \_\ \/ /_/
     /        \
```

Lets name its wedges as:

```
       4      3
     5\__    __/2
      /_/ /\ \_\
     __ \ \/ / __
     \_\_\/\/_/_/
6__/\___\_\/_/___/\__1
7  \/ __/_/\_\__ \/  12
     /_/ /\/\ \_\
      __/ /\ \__
      \_\ \/ /_/
     8/        \11
       9     10
```

For creating the above snow flake, all we need is to first construct a single wedge (say 1) and fit others in place based on wedge 1.

**Wedge Construction**

Lets consider the wedges 1 and 2 from the above example and shade all the blocks which belong to wedge 1 with `x`.

```
    /2       x
   _\     xxx
  / __ xxxxx
 /_/xxxxxxx
/xxxxxxxxx1
```

We can see that exactly 25 `x` belong to wedge 1 in a 50 block trapezium of wedge 1 and 2. The height of the trapezium corresponds to the input integer `N` and the base length of the trapezium is `2N`.

To construct the wedge 1, follow these instructions:

- Use only the area marked for your wedge (For example, the `x` area in the above image for wedge 1)
- Use uni-directional random walk to fill up the `x` using the characters `/`, `_` and `\`
- There should be at least 1 path in the random walk which connects the left most `x` with any one of the right most `x` of each row.

A few examples of valid random walks for wedge 1 are:

[TBC]

---

***Random Ants***

This is still a bit hazy but the challenge would involve making random ants out of the following ants:

```
 \_/
'-0-'
--0--
.-0-.

 \_/
'-0-'
--0--
.-0-.

 \_/
'-0-'
--0--
.-0-.


 \O/
'-O-'
 /o\
  ^

 \O/
'-O-'
 /o\
  ^

 \O/
'-O-'
 /o\
```

---

***Fish Aquarium***

````
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         .               `         /
                          .    ,../...       .
          .                .  /       `\  /  .
     \    .        o         < '  )     =<
     /\  .                    \ \      /  \   .  __
   >=)'>                       `'\'"'"'         /o \/
     \/ .    /         o              /,        \__/\    .:/
     /   .  /--\ /         /         <')=<     .      ,,///;,   ,;/
           <o)  =<      . / \         \`         .   o:::::::;;///
            \__/ \       <')_=<                     >::::::::;;\\\
             \            \_/            .            ''\\\\\'' ';\
    (                      \              .   __
     )                                       <'_><          (
    (          (                ,/..          `              )
     )     (    )             <')   `=<                )    (
    (       )  (               ``\```                 (      )
_____)_____(____)______________________________________)____(___________
````

Comment: I like (1) and (2) more than (3) and (4) because they are more structured, so more can be done with algorithms rather than compression.

Comment: @xnor 3 is not finalized yet, so I may do 4 before 3. But 3 would have more structure to it once done. I agree that 4 does not have much similarity, but there still is scope for reuse in 4.

Answer (score 4):

## Super Smash Bots

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This is an idea for a KOTH based off of the Super Smash Bros video game series by Nintendo.

The basic mechanics of this KOTH would be an every-man-for-himself battle between a large number of players simultaneously.  Players can execute a variety of moves, like short/medium/long-ranged attacks or blocking.  As opposed to most combat-based games, players do not have a health bar, but rather die when knocked off of the stage (the arena).  When an attack hits a player, it deals damage to that player but also causes knockback.  The amount of knockback a player experiences is proportional to the total amount of damage he's received so far in the game.

### The Arena

The game takes place on a vertical stage with gravity.  There will be several fixed platforms surrounded by empty space.  A player too far from a platform is killed.  More ideas about the design of the stage are covered in the Stage Design section.

### Character Selection?

The actual game offers players the selection of different *characters*, each of which have different abilities, strengths, and weaknesses.  If I am to include character selection, that will be a way for players to pick the strategy they think works best and choose a bot that has those strengths.  Another KOTH which had this feature was the Pokemon-themed KOTH (citation needed).

On the other hand, balancing stuff can be hard.

### Actions

- **Move.**  Simple as that.  Well, not exactly.  I think this could make a very good contender for a continuous-surface (not a grid) area.  On a surface, the character would walk, while airborne, the character's movement doesn't respond as quickly.
- **Jump.**  Is like a move, but vertical.  More specifically, this gives the player an upward velocity.  Double jumping might be possible.
- **Short Range.**  This deals damage to an immediately adjacent player.
- **Medium Range.**  This deals damage to players within a certain range.  It would likely involve your player physically moving as well.
- **Long Range.**  This creates a projectile, which can deal damage to a player in the specified direction, no matter the distance.
- **Area of Effect.**  All players within a given range take a little damage.

### Respawning?

Is is often typical that players have three lives, and thus must be killed three times to be eliminated.  By respawning players, the variance of each match outcome should be reduced.

### Game Ticks

If I'm doing a continuous-field, then I would want something the emulates continuous movement.  In order to give fair processing time, I can't really have all of the entrant programs running at once in an asynchronous fashion. Some possible solutions are as follows.

1. Priority Queue

   - Each action taken creates a certain time delay before the player can move again.  Standing still is shortest delay, moving is second-shortest, and long-ranged attacks have the longest delay.
   - Turn order is determined by a priority queue.  From the list of players, the player with the least delay is selected.  Then, the game's physics are simulated for that amount of time ("virtual" time, not "true" time) and that much time is subtracted from everyone's delay.  The selected player picks an action, and he is put back into the queue with that move's delay.
   - This creates a period of vulnerability after an attack which may be game-mechanically interesting.
2. Random Time-Steps

   - Play occurs in a semi-random order, with random, non-uniform time-steps between moves.  This makes it so that the player cannot predict exactly what the world will be like in the future, or guarantee the exact timings of any moves.
   - After each player has taken a single move, the order of players would be scrambled.
   - Time-step duration would be approximately constant with a random variation of +/-20% or something like that.

### Animation

This would be *really cool* to watch, but I don't think I could possibly animate this by myself.

### Stage Design

Stage design will be important, because a large chunk of the entrant programs will be tailored the stage.  I don't really have any clue what I'm doing here.

**One idea I've had is to crowd-source the stage design.**

Maybe something with a few ledges, like this?  (scaled down for ASCII-artability)

```
..........................
..........................
...XXXX...................
...............XXXXXXX....
..........................
....XXXXXXXXXXXXX.........
..........................
```

I could add some more features like so:

```
..........................
....XXXX..................
........XXXXX.....XXXX...
......................\...
..XXXXXXXXXXXXX....XXXXX..
................../.......
............XXXXXX........
..........................
```

The slants represent ramps that the player could walk up.

### Player Navigation

I foresee one of the most difficult things for entrants to do is to navigate the stage.  Each player would definitely receive a copy of the current stage and players as input every turn (or as arguments/parameters, more details on that below).

I may choose to offload a bunch of pathfinding stuff onto the controller so that entrants, if they so desire, can give the destination and have their character move there.  Given that the stage would be constant, this should not be difficult for the controller to do.  On the other hand, the continuous-field design can make pathfinding more complicated.

One thing to consider during stage design is the ease of pathfinding.

### Vertical or Horizontal?

Pretty much the whole proposal has been assuming a vertical map.  I could change this to horizontal to allow a larger number of people to fight in one match.

### Classes or Full Programs, and Language?

Personally, I think this would be easiest to do as a Java KOTH with classes. It will run quick(-er than several other methods) and I could give entrants access to a variety of methods that give information about the stage.

### Controller

Literally no work has been done yet.

Answer (score 4):

> Sandbox note : Big change in specs, mainly for balancing issues (thanks to @trichoplax for your sugeestions :))
>
> Major changes : Starting, Turn deroulement (2 phases from now), tie-break, Cloning. Merging may be removed due to the new specs (rendered pretty useless).
>
> With the current specs, 1000 turn migh be WAAAAAAY to much, as you could easily go up to the 17 range... well, you could reach it in 3 turns, and with 3 turns more you could wipe everything with an explode.... Will fix that

## Summoner war

tags : [king-of-the-kill](/questions/tagged/king-of-the-kill)[java](/questions/tagged/java)

You're a Summoner controlling Demons. Regulary, some tournament are done to dertermine who will be the king. And the king is always the strongest !

As it is a turn-based game, each Summoner will play twice against each opponent. So, for each pair of submission, they will all fight while playing first AND playing last.

A fight is limited to 1000 turns.
A turn is the cumulated actions of both Masters.

The winner of a fight is the one who totally destroyed all the demons of the opponent. The number of Demons you killed will be used as tie-breaker

The winner of the tournament is the Summoner who won the most fights. The same tie-breaker as for fights is used, except it is the cumulated amount of kill :).

### The Grid

The grid is 9*17 and the cells are placed as above :

```
.................
.................
.6..1.......1..6.
.................
.5..2.......2..5.
.................
.4..3.......3..4.
.................
.................
```

The numbers indicates the position of the starting Demons. Each Summoner will   see itself as the left Summoner.
Demons can move and attack on horizontal lines, vertical lines and diagonals.

### Starting

You will chose up to 6 Demons to summon, determining their stats and their capacities. 
You can give a maximum of 12 stat point distributed among your Demons
Each Demon you summon (at this moment) will cost you 2 points.

> Summoning 6 demons will cost 6*2=12 points
>
> Summoning 3 demons will cost you 3*2=6 points, leaving you 6 points to increase their statistics.

### Statistics

Demons have 4 statistics :

```
 Life 
    Hp = 2+Life
    If the hp of your Demon reach 0, it dies.
 Attack
    Determine the damages you deal/heal
 Defense
    Reduct all incoming damages by defense/2 rounded to superior. 
    You can't take less than 1 (except if you're attacked for 0 hit points)
 Range 
    Determine the range of your attacks
```

### Basic Moves

There's 3 moves that every Demons can do :

```
 Move
    The Demons will move by one unit.
 Attack
    Deal damages to the Demon in an adjacent cell.
    Damages: attack+1
 Explode
    Destroy the Demon and deal damages to it's surrounding.
    It only can be used if your Demon have more than 40% hp.
    It does raw damages (defense doesn't influence it).
    Damages: attack/2 (raw)
    Radius : 1+sqrt(range)  (square shaped, truncated)
```

### Capacities

Each Demon will have one capacity in the following list:

```
 Merge
    Allows a Demon to absorb an other adding their stats 
    During the merge process, you chose if you want to keep Merge as a capacity, 
    or if you want to take the other Demon's capacity.
    After merging, a Demon won't be able to clone again.
 Heal
    Heal nearby Demons but not self.
    Heal: attack/2  rounded to superior
    Radius : range+1(square)
 Cross
    Deal damages on all lines or diagonals around your Demon
    It will damages on lines if the direction you specify is
    North/South/East/West/Self
    Otherwise, it will damages on the diagonals.
    Damages : attack
    Radius : range+1(lines or diagonals)
 Eat
    Steal some stats if it kills the target
    The target must be on an adjacent cell.
    Damages : attack
    Stat stolen : range (maximum)
                The stat stolen will be distributed randomly between the stats
                of your Demon. It cannot steal more point that the opponent 
                Demon have.
```

### Misc

You may give an optional name for your Demons. This name will only be known by you, and could be useful if you want to remember the role you gave to your Demons. This name could be changed at anytime.

### Turn deroulement

Each player's turn has 2 steps : the enhance phase and the battle phase.

A turn is derouling as following :

```
player 1's enhancing phase
player 2's enhancing phase
player 1's battle phase
player 2's battle phaes
```

#### Enhance phase

Each turn, you will be given 6+nbTurn/50 stats points.

```
On turn 1, you will have 6 points.
On turn 50, 7 points. 
On turn 1000, 26 points.
```

Those points will stack upon time if you don't use them.

```
On turn 1, I had 6 points, I used 4 remain :2
Turn 2, I gain 6 points more, I can use 8.
etc ...
```

Those points can either be used to increase the stats of your Demons (1 point = 1 life||attack||defense||range) or to clone them.

To clone a Demon, you must use `2+life+attack+defense+range` points. In result, the origin demon will have his points halved, and a clone with the other half will spawn.

```
Let's say I want to clone the following demon :
 life=2
 attack=2
 defense=5
 range=0
 capacity=Cross
He has 2+2+5+0 = 9 statistics points, so I would need 2+9=11 points.
The resulting Demons would both be :
 life=1
 attack=1
 defense=3 (yes, stats are rounded to superior :))
 range=0
 capacity=Cross
```

Battle phase
At the start of the battle phase, you will be given :

- The current tableboard
- A list containing your Demons and all the information about them
- A list containing the stats and position of your opponent's Demons

You will return the actions of all your Demons.

> you have up to x ms to return this list (not decided yet)

Once you've chosen your actions, the following will happen :

- Every Demons which had to move, will move. If two Demons try to move to the same location, they will both stay still.
- All the actions which change the hp(heal/damages) will happens at the same time.
- Finally, your turn end, and your opponent's will decide his actions.

### Submissions

Each submission will be written in Java. You can't interact with other players nor the controller in any way you could imagine.

You must extend the following class :

> Class not yet developped
>
> A github link will be provided, for the controller etc.

### Sandbox notes

I'm aware that there's plenty typos and errors, I will correct them before the final version. Some text and clarification might be added.
As it can be complicated (lot of options), 4 demonstration Summoner will be provided (and will be in the pool), each of them using only some functionnality (prooving that you don't have to use every single thing).

I'm not done yet with all the sources for the controller/field etc. An API will be provided for extracting/using informations easily. 
Once it will be complete, I will put a time limit for the execution of one turn.
If I have time, I will provide an interface to see the fights with colors etc.

Questions :

- Is this too complex? I'd like to know if to much options are given, and if it's confusing (ie, if you don't know where to start).
- Is there some points of the ruleset that are obviously dangerous for the good health of this contest.
- Any suggestion?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I've removed all `<code></code>` tags and instead selected the code and pressed ctrl-K (which adds 4 spaces before the code). This formats as a code block, instead of a series of code lines with white gaps between. I find this much easier to read so I've edited it in for you to see, but feel free to rollback to the previous edit (I thought it would be easier to edit and show, rather than try to describe).

Comment: Ho, thank you, did not know the K^ thing ! I didn't think it was hard to read with it, that's why I did put <code> instead of spaces. Anyway, thanks :).

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Katenkyo I'm not certain but wouldn't it be possible just to fill the whole grid by cloning? Which would make it quite hard to develop an effective strategy (because clone leaves two demon with potentially full health- it might work if it shares the health between the clones)- or is that the idea (make a massive army of demons and then fight?

Comment: @TheE I think the AoE could compensate this point. One Demon with a good attack stat (via merging/eating) could one-shot a big number of your Demon/turn.
I want the "fill with clones" strategy to be possible, but with a little more thinking to be competitive. I don't know yet if it is owerpowered. Anyway, it have to be tested ! Thanks for the case, didn't think of it. Will test it as soon as the controller is up.

Comment: Minor point: the list of standard moves still refers to 4 instead of 3 moves.

Comment: Explode affects a radius of 1 + sqrt(range). Is this a square range or some other shape (Euclidean to give an approximate circle?). Is the sqrt rounded up or down?

Comment: square range, round down (so 16 range will effectively add 4 points) I did that because you'd only need 17 range to wipe out the entire map with raw damages... No you still can have a good range, but it's harder

Comment: What if the cross affected both players (so you need to get into the right position or else accept that some of your own demons will be hit too)? Would that be interesting or just awkward? How would it affect the balance of the different capacities?

Comment: What if explode and heal also affected both players (all demons in range)?

Comment: @trichoplax I'm thinking about it since the beginning, but I am not able to make my mind about it... I mean, sure it is interesting, and all but... Isn't it too much? You already have to manage lots of demons, to buff/clone them, be aware of your opponents. So I don't know, I can't know, if that would be too difficult to handle...

Comment: I was thinking less about how complicated it is and more about whether it would make the capacities more balanced. I think the main problem would be if one of the capacities is too strong and everyone chooses nothing else.

Comment: @trichoplax sounds logic. I'll look at a way to implement it :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ironclad Tactics KoTH

This KoTH is inspired by the Ironclad Tactics paper version from Zachtronics.

The game is played on a 9x4 grid split into three areas: the North, the South, and No-Man's-Land (the center).  To make things easier for you, it will always appear that you are the North (the left).

[image: Steelclad]

Each battle, each player starts with 10 Action Points (AP).  In a battle, there are 4 phases: Selection, Placement, Upgrading, then Attacking.

### Selection

During selection, players start by each simultaneously choosing an upgrade to ban, and then choosing 5 of the 8 or 9 remaining upgrades they wish to use.  The chosen upgrades are not revealed to their opponent.

### Placement

During placement, players simultaneously place an Ironclad until they decide to drop out of the phase or they have used all of their AP.  Each placement costs 1AP, and Ironclads can only be placed on the player's respective side and No-Man's-Land.

### Upgrading

During upgrading, players simultaneously upgrade one of their Ironclads using their remaining AP until they decide to drop out of the phase or they have used all of their AP.  Each upgrade costs 2+(# of times you previously used the upgrade)-(# of times your opponent previously used the upgrade), with a minimum cost of 0.

There are 10 possible upgrades:

[image: Upgrades]

The stars represent Ironclads, and each circle represents the squares the Ironclad will attack.  The arrow represents the *Saboteur* upgrade, which will give the player 2 additional victory points, and the diamond represents the *Heavy Chassis* upgrade, which requires 2 hits to be destroyed.

Upgrades can be given to any of your unupgraded Ironclads, even if the squares it would attack fall off of the board.  Upgrades do not need to be given to all Ironclads.

### Attacking

During attacking, all Ironclads simultaneously attack.  Any Ironclad in the square of attack (even if the attack is friendly) is destroyed (unless the tank has the *Heavy Chassis* upgrade, in which case it must be attacked by two different tanks.

Any remaining tanks give 1 (or 3, if the tank has the *Saboteur upgrade) victory point(s) if they have a horizontal line of sight to the opposite end unobstructed by undestroyed enemy tanks.

---

## API

You will implement a Java class.  *more info*

## Additional Info

- You will have 10 battles against each opponent.
- The price for upgrades resets after each opponent.
- You beat an opponent by having more victory points than them after the 10 battles.  You win this challenge by beating the most opponents.
- If both players attempt to place in the same spot at the same time, that location becomes unplaceable for the rest of the battle, and players must place again.
  -

Answer (score 4):

## Musical Washing Machine

I have a washing machine with a knob and several buttons.  The knob selects the type of laundry and the buttons cycle through water temperature, etc. options. When pressed, these each create a musical note.  There are five musical notes that can be made, in this ascending order: F A C D E

```
knob (K)
   When 360ed: play D and reset all other buttons
wash temp (T)
   1st press (cool -> warm): A
   2nd press (warm -> hot): F
   3rd press (hot -> cold): E
   4th press (cold -> cool): C
   (repeat)
spin speed (S)
   1st press (medium -> max extract): F
   2nd press (max extract -> no spin): E
   3rd press (no spin -> medium): A
   (repeat)
soil level (L)
   1st press (medium -> heavy): A
   2nd press (heavy -> extra heavy): F
   3rd press (extra heavy -> light): E
   4th press (light -> medium): C
   (repeat)
```

## The Challenge

Given a series of notes, determine if if can be played on my washing machine, and, if so, output the series of moves to generate it.

I/O coming soon to a washing machine near you

Comment: As a side note, there is a washing machine that plays the [New Zealand Athem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssfgviSbMgk)

Comment: I think I understand, but it looks a bit confusing. Maybe you should give an example with an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## BrainCubed

You are the proud maintainer of one of the smartest robots in the world. Well, it used to be. Now its speakers and microphones have been broken and the darn thing only seems to read [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck). To make matters worse, it would appear most of its RAM... disappeared? This will be tough to explain to the boss. No matter. It seems to have figured out how to draw on a whiteboard to supplement its now-shoddy memory, and you have bigger problems on your hands.

You need to know how to fit things in cubes.

### The Task

Lately, your biggest problems (aside from the embarrassing conversation with your boss later) have to do with volume. Cubing things is hard. That's why you'll get the robot to do it for you! Your goal in this challenge is to write a Brainfuck program that computes the cube of a given number. However, the robot's whiteboard isn't very big. **The less memory your Brainfuck program requires, the better.**

### Input

You will receive a single integer as input, `x`.

- You may choose to accept input in any integer base greater than `0` and less than or equal to `36`, so long as this base does not vary from input to input. (e.g. binary, hexadecimal, decimal)
- You may assume that `x` is in the range `0 <= x <= 2^16 - 1`
- You should take input as a string of *characters*, not bytes. For example, if `x = 33` and my program accepts input in binary, I should receive the string "100001" (bytes: 49 48 48 48 48 49) *not* simply bytes containing 100001.

### Output

- Your Brainfuck program must output the value of `x^3` in the **same** base that input was received in.
- As it is for input, your program should output a *string* of ASCII characters, not a sequence of bytes.
- The program must terminate, and should not print anything except for its numerical output.

### Rules and Scoring

Your score in this challenge is defined in the following manner:
Let the tape of the Brainfuck memory be described as having a `1`st element at the left-most position, and then with potentially infinite cells to the right, indexed by increasing integers `n`.

Let `N(x)` denote the right-most (highest `n`) cell that the program ever sends the tape pointer to (**not** necessarily modified) for a given input `x`.
Your score for this challenge is then `sum (x = 0, 1, 2, ... 100) N(x)` (modification pending)

In order to verify score, you may use [this] (soon) modified interpreter.

- Your program must be written entirely in Brainfuck.
- Assume the highest value a cell can hold is `255` before wrapping to `0`, and that moving left off of the tape will cause the robot to suddenly and violently crash.
- Your program should not exceed 10k bytes, nor should it take more than 10 minutes to compute `x^3` for any `x <= 2^16 - 1` on a relatively modern machine.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)[optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

#### SANDBOX NOTES

What do you think of BF memory-optimization as a basis for a challenge?

I chose cubing `x` as a challenge that is not so trivial as to allow for different approaches, but still within the grasp of BF (if different bases are allowed). Any other ideas?

Comment: How is the base determined? For example, if the input is `2`, how is it determined if that's base-10 (and so output `8`) or base-8 (and so output `10`)?

Comment: My thought was along the same lines as TimmyD: the obvious cheat is to just read the digit, write it, and then write `00` and claim that the input was in base `x`.

Comment: @TimmyD Ack! My post is unclear. I meant that **you**, as the programmer, may choose what base you expect your input/output to be in. e.g. I can write a BF program that accepts input in base 16 and outputs in base 16, or use ternary if I think it'll help me use less memory. I didn't mean that the base changes from input to input. Thank you for the feedback, I'll certainly try to clear that up!

Comment: What is the largest allowed input base? Also, the maximum input needs to be bigger: the current rules probably allow hardcoding of all the outputs.

Comment: @feersum Good points. I'll cap it at `36` to avoid the general silliness of trying to figure out what symbols to use. I understand your concern, but I want to keep the upper limit fairly small. I think `2^16 - 1` should do the trick?

Comment: @BrainSteel That should be good enough, as long as there are some test cases throughout the range.

Answer (score 4):

## Pi, continued

**The task: generate an arbitrarily precise rational approximation to pi by using a continued fraction.**

One way to calculate pi is by using this continued fraction ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction)):

[image]

The first few approximations can be calculated as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**You may not use this particular continued fraction.** The reason is that in order to calculate this sequence to arbitrary precision, you have to *already* know pi to arbitrary precision. The series `[3,7,15,1,292,...]` does not repeat, like pi's own digits.

However, there *are* continued fractions that have a regular structure. You may use any of these you wish (like [these on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction)) in your program.

### The rules

- Input: a single, non-negative integer `n`.
- Output: the `n`th (improper) fraction in your chosen continued fraction series, in lowest terms.
- Output may be in any form, provided that these conditions are met: 1) the same base is used for numerator and denominator (and for all fractions), 2) the numerator and denominator are clearly distinguishable, and 3) the numerator comes first.
- Your program *must* use a continued fraction. It *may not* use any summation series like the approximation formulae [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80).

### Meta

- I feel like some of this may be confusing. What can I clear up, and how?
- Is it misleading to introduce continued fractions by using an unpredictable series when I want users to use ones that have a regular structure?

Comment: It looks good to me. As long as you don't mind the example being valid for use in an answer, yes it does seem to make sense to use one of the regular structured ones for the example. That way someone who doesn't read it properly can just use the example without realising there are other options, and you get fewer annoying questions...

Comment: Yes, it is misleading to start with the unpredictable series. Are you ruling out approximating pi with a built-in or other limit (that is not a summation), then computing the continued fraction from that? The examples you link are generalized continued fractions, which can have numerators other than 1 and summands that are not whole -- I take it those are allowed?

Comment: The nth term in a continued fraction series is well defined modulo possible out-by-one disagreements in the indexing. But for generalised continued fractions, there are three competing definitions: if the gcf is `x = b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2 / (b_2 + ... ))` is the sequence `b_0`, `b_0 + a_1`, `b_0 + a_1 / b_1`, `b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2)`, `b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2 / b_2)`, ...; or is it `b_0`, `b_0 + a_1 / b_1`, `b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2 / b_2)`, ...; or is it `b_0 + a_1`, `b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2)`, `b_0 + a_1 / (b_1 + a_2 / (b_2 + a_3))`, ...?

Comment: Regarding the competing definitions, I think the cleanest resolution would be to allow any pattern that adds one layer at a time in a consistent fashion, which allows any of the examples as well as off-by-one disagreements.

Answer (score 4):

### Rotate / Flip a Unicode Box Drawing

Given a Unicode box drawing, followed by a series of rotate and/or flip commands, output the result of those operations on the drawing.  For clarification, a box drawing can be made from the following characters:

```
─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘ ├ ┤ ┬ ┴ ┼
═ ║ ╔ ╗ ╚ ╝ ╠ ╣ ╦ ╩ ╬
    ╒ ╕ ╘ ╛ ╞ ╡ ╤ ╧ ╪
    ╓ ╖ ╙ ╜ ╟ ╢ ╥ ╨ ╫
```

The rotate and flip commands are also presented using Unicode symbols:

```
↔  Flip the drawing horizontally
↕  Flip the drawing vertically
↷ Rotate the drawing 90° clockwise
↶ Rotate the drawing 90° counter-clockwise
↯  Convert all single lines to double and vice versa (Optional - 10% bonus)
```

All other characters should remain unchanged, but moved to fit where they would be in the modified drawing.  For example, if given the inputs:

```
Input   Output          Input   Output
 ┌┴╖     ╓┴┐             ┌┴╖     ╔═╕
 │A║     ║A│             │E║     ╣E├
 ╘╦╝     ╚╦╛             ╘╦╝     ╙─┘
 ↔                       ↔↷

 ┌┴╖     ╒╩╗             ┌┴╖     ┌─╖
 │B║     │B║             │F║     ┤F╠
 ╘╦╝     └┬╜             ╘╦╝     ╘═╝
 ↕                       ↷↔

 ┌┴╖     ╓─┐             ┌┴╖     ╔╩╕
 │C║     ╣C├             │G║     ║G│
 ╘╦╝     ╚═╛             ╘╦╝     ╙┬┘
 ↷                      ↶↶

 ┌┴╖     ╒═╗             ┌┴╖     ╔╩╕
 │D║     ┤D╠             │H║     ║H│
 ╘╦╝     └─╜             ╘╦╝     ╙┬┘
 ↶                      ↔↕
```

The drawing may be of any size (let's say anywhere from 1×1 to 50×50), and not necessarily square.

The flip and rotate commands will always occur after any drawing to be flipped, and by themselves on one single line.  They should be executed from left to right.  (Note that order matters - the E and F examples use the same two commands but in reverse order, and produce different results.)

There may be an arbitrary number of flips and rotates, but you'll note that there are only 8 possible end-states for the final drawing.  The G and H examples show two different sets of commands that produce the same result (other than the letter in the middle).  It is possible that a series of commands will result in simply returning to the original drawing.

Input may be supplied via command line, user input, file I/O, or any other means you see fit.  (Though it should obviously support multiple lines of input.  You may use `\n` to represent line breaks if your input mode only supports a single line.)  Likewise, output may be to the screen or a file at your discretion.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Some more complicated examples:

```
Input    Output        Input    Output
          ┌─┐                    ┌─┐
          │A│                    │B│
┌─╥─┐     ╞═╡          ┌─╥─┐     ╞═╡
│A║B│     │B│          │A║B│     │A│
└─╨─┘     └─┘          └─╨─┘     └─┘
↷                     ↶

   Input           Output
┌─┐╔═╗╒══╓──    ──╖══╕╔═╗┌─┐
├─┘╠═╝│  ║ ╖    ╓ ║  │╚═╣└─┤
│  ║  ╘══╙─╜    ╙─╜══╛  ║  │
↔

┌─┐╔═╗╒══╓──    ╔═╗┌─┐╓──╒══
├─┘╠═╝│  ║ ╖    ╠═╝├─┘║  │ ╕
│  ║  ╘══╙─╜    ║  │  ╙──╘═╛
↯

┌─┐╔═╗╒══╓──    ┌─┐╔═╗╒══╓──
├─┘╠═╝│  ║ ╖    ├─┘╠═╝│  ║ ╖
│  ║  ╘══╙─╜    │  ║  ╘══╙─╜
↔↯↷↷↕↶↯↶↕↔
```

Comment: You should have examples where characters other than the box move, the box is a different size and with more than one box, if that is allowed. This looks like a good challenge, but one that is likely to be rife with ambiguity.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - I chose one starting box which is asymmetrical just as a simple example.  I could add a couple more complicated shapes - I was thinking this could be applied to any shape using the box-drawing symbols, not just a simple box.

Answer (score 4):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

## City Life

#### A cellular automation war game.

In this game, each player will control group of cites on a grid. Each city takes up one cell, and all cells with no city are "wilderness", and have no owner. The game will consist of a series of rounds, called "generations". Play continues until a player gets 1000 points, or 200 rounds, whichever happens first.

### Setup

The board will start with one city controlled by each player. It will be square with sides length `ceil(sqrt(25*n))` for an `n` player game. Cities will be placed randomly in such a way that no two cities will see each other the first round.

### Phase 1: give orders

At the start of each generation, each city gets n actions where `n = # of adjacent wilderness spaces + 2`. So a city surrounded by wilderness gets 10 actions while a city surrounded by cites gets only 2. The Actions will be divided into these three categories:

`Attack/Spread` : used to Attack Cites or spread into the wilderness.

- Takes a direction as a parameter. Will add one "Attacker" to that cell, even if the cell is a city with the same owner. (See **resolve attacks**)

`Defend` : used to protect your city.

- Will add one to the defender count of the city performing this action. (If no defend actions are used, the city will become wilderness.)

`Score` : used to win.

- Adds one to the score the cites owner.

### Phase 2: resolve attacks

After all cites have put in orders, all cells are checked for takeover.

- A wilderness cell will become a city if at least three attackers are there. The new city's owner will be determined randomly from among the attackers.(for example, if player A sent 2 attackers and player B sent 3, than A has a 2/5 chance of owning the new city)
- A city will become wilderness if the number of attackers is equal to the number of defenders (even if both are 0).
- A city is taken over if their are more attackers than defenders. The city's new owner is determined randomly from among the attackers, as above.

**After the round is complete, all attackers and defenders are reset.**

---

To enter the competition, you must create a bot to perform the "give orders" step. All bots will be written in JavaScript.

### I/O

You will provide a character to represent your city and a function that takes as parameters:

1. Your vision. each city can see a 5x5 square with the city as its center. It will be represented as an array of arrays of characters, `" "` representing wilderness, and each players character to represent their cites.

Example:

if you have a map like This ("Y" represents you)

```
+-----+   
|AA  B|    N
|A    |    ▲
|  YY | W< O >E
|C   C|    V
|   C |    S
+-----+
```

Your sight parameter will be:

```
[["A","A"," "," ","B"],["A"," "," "," "," "],[" "," ","Y","Y"," "],["C"," "," "," ","C"],[" "," "," ","C"," "]]`
```

2. The number of actions you can perform this turn. (which can be calculated, but I will give it to you as most bots will need it.)

You must return an array of strings, each string representing an order.

`"N"` - Attack North

`"NE"`- Attack North east

`"W"` - Attack West

...

`"D"` - Defend

`"$"` - Score

If you return more moves than you have actions allotted, the moves at the end of the array will be ignored. If you have less, extra moves will be set to `"D"`.

---

I have made a controller that is reasonable, although I would like add to it and finalize the rules before publishing. If you have any advice or criticism, please comment below.

---

#### Example Answer:

---

## Random Bot [?]

```
function(map, moveCount){
    var allMoves = ["N","S","E","W","NE","NW","SE","SW","D","$"];
    var orders = [];
    while(orders.length < moveCount){
        orders.push(allMoves[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]);
    }
    return orders;
}
```

This bot will just assign a random move for each action. Its cites are represented by `?`.

Comment: I think you left off a row in the map.  You should also clarify whether attackers and defenders are persistent or must be re-assigned each turn.

Comment: "*A city can become wilderness if the number of attackers is equal to the number of defenders*" implies to me that there's a random element. Is that so? If not, I suggest replacing *can* with *will*.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you, fixed.

Comment: I've been thinking more. It would be good to state the initial density (or, in other words, how the size of the world varies with the number of players). In the interests of fairness, probably also worth guaranteeing that the initial cities will have a certain buffer region (and in particular, that two of them won't start next to each other and a third in a nice open space); and that the topology will be toroidal (so the board wraps both horizontally and vertically). Finally, I would make it explicit that you can attack your own city, but not "support" it (i.e. lend it defenders).

Answer (score 4):

## Random Physics Golf #1: Net Gravitational Force [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Introduction to the Series

Every week or so I will be posting a physics challenge. My goal here is to design challenges that in the end, teach some people some physics. Overall, the challenges will be very basic with little information. All of these challenges will have the minimal information necessary to solve them, and the goal is for users like you to do some research, watch some videos, and understand how these concepts work to teach you how to approach these types of physics problems and explain how they work. Of course, I will also give two optional hints per challenge, which are there if you do not have the time or determination to do the research, or you cannot figure out how to do the problem after researching. The two hints will be "necessary equations for this challenge" and "process to solve the problem". The hints are completely optional to use and it is encourages to not use them, but as stated above to learn the information for yourself. The series will have one main leaderboard. Whoever has the least combined byte count for all of the challenges gets a *to be determined* prize. Each challenge will range in difficulty, with an upwards trend of difficulty. I wish you all luck and I hope you learn a thing or two!

### Challenge #1: Net Gravitational Force

**Note 1: this challenge highly requires knowledge of the mathematical *vector* quantity, if you do not know what that is, I suggest reading [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-a-vector.html) and [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Vector-Addition) before attempting this challenge.**

**Note 2: this challenge considers gravity in *CLASSICAL MECHANICS*. Disregard general relativity for this challenge.**

Lets start with the definition of a force. A force is a *vector* quantity, a number with both direction and magnitude. Simply put, force is mass times acceleration. Many mathematicians will know the name of this formula as *Newton's Second Law*. Now, that is a well known formula, but here is something less known: all forces are classified in one of four categories: *weak nuclear*, *strong nuclear*, *electromagnetic*, and *gravitational*. These four are called the *four fundamental forces of the universe*. We will be focusing on the gravitational force in this called.

The gravitational force is then classified as a *field force*. This means that the force acts on all objects in a certain radius around another object. In this case, gravity pulls down on objects from anywhere in a radius around them. However, I still have not defined where gravity comes from. Well, the simple answer is from *mass*. An object with more mass has a bigger gravitational pull on objects around it. In case you are wondering, the earth has a gravitational pull of `-9.81 m/s^2` (an object will gain `9.8 m/s` of downward velocity every second). But here is where it gets fun: because gravity comes from *mass*, every object with mass has a *gravitational pull*. This is where you come in. I want you to calculate the *net gravitational pull* of all the objects surrounding another object. Here is a better explanation:

You will receive co-ordinates and masses of objects in space for input. So an example input could be visualized as this:
[image]
You can easily see each force being applied on the target object by the three larger objects. Objects will smaller masses have a smaller gravitational field (as shown by the orange force arrow). Your job in this challenge is to find the *net gravitational force* being acted on the target object. To do this, it is a simple vector addition problem with the forces from the other objects. So, the resultant vector (net force), may look something like this:
[image]
This is all of the information that I will give you. It is now your job to find the equations, and research how this all works.

### Challenge Specs

- Input will be several lists of numbers consisting of the `x co-ordinate`, `y co-ordinate`, and `mass` of each object. The numbers could be either integers or decimals. You may take this in any convienent format (`[[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]`, `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]` and `1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9` are all acceptable. The first list of inputs will always be the target object (red in the pictures above), and the other lists will be the other objects. All inputs will have at least two objects. No objects will have the same co-ordinates.
- Output will be two numbers, in any human-readable format, in any order. One will be the *magnitude* of the net force, using your desired unit system (SI, Planck units, Imperial units, etc.) and the other will be the *direction* in *radians OR degrees* of the net force. Output must be precise to the least number of significant figures in the input (`Input: 2, 3.5, 6.1 -> Output: 200 (232.34 before rounding)`, note this is not an actual test case). Output may or may not be in scientific notation, its up to you.
- You may assume input will not cause any error during execution, and you may assume all inputs will be valid.

***META NOTE: Help me decide the precision of the output: http://strawpoll.me/6825341***

### Test Cases

***Meta Note: WIP***

### Hints

These hints are for those who do not want to put in the time and effort of research, or those who could not find a solution. So, here are the two hints:

#### Hint 1: Equations:

You need the following equations for this challenge:

> [image]
>
> You will also need the standard vector equations for this challenge:
>
> [image]

#### Hint 2: Sample Solution Process:

It would take up too much space to fit it all here, so I made [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byu4AFDjMDT1aTFDMjN5LTlmTVk/view?usp=sharing) to aid you for this hint.

### Leaderboard

***Meta Note: blah blah blah, working leaderboard will eventually go here! This leaderboard will contain and combine scores for all of the weekly challenges. It will only be visible on this question, though.***

Comment: The input format currently is cumbersome, requiring string parsing. I would recommend loosening it to allow input as a list of 3-tuples (or similar representations). You should also specify whether the inputs will be integers or decimals.

Comment: @Mego I took your recommendations. Does that look good?

Comment: "*Output must be precise to at least three decimal places*" would get a rebuke from every physics teacher I ever had. Surely it should be to a number of *significant figures* which depends on the s.f. of the input?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, this is a programming challenge, and sig-fig calculations would (IMO) overly complicate the answers. (If your comment was a joke/sarcasm sorry ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Create a spiraling image

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

#### Introduction

WIP

#### Task

Given an image, output the image with a spiraling effect.

#### Scoring

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the submission with the highest number of votes wins!

#### Test cases

Note that your program should work for images with any size. The output should be a **512×512px image**. Also, *note that the test cases are **examples***, you may use any algorithm to produce these images and do not have to match the images below. Use your creativity!

**Test case 1**

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

**Test case 2**

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

**Test case 3**

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

**Test case 4**

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

**Test case 5**

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

#### Important

The full size images:

- [Test case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8FzR.jpg)
- [Test case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9oR4.jpg)
- [Test case 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1JQp.png)
- [Test case 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP1Fk.png)
- [Test case 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Sxy.png)

Comment: What counts as the Droste effect does not appear to be clearly defined here, and some of the example outputs are hard to justify as exhibiting the effect. The chat image in particular doesn't seem to have any repetition of the image within itself, only distortion of the scale.

Comment: @trichoplax Oh, you're right. That isn't even a Droste image. I should probably remove the "Droste" thing and make something else out of it. Maybe define it as a "spiral" image.

Comment: Either way it sounds like the too-broad end of the popularity contest spectrum. For a Droste image challenge you could probably make it well defined enough to not need to be a pop con if you also have a template as input, defining one or more places where the image needs to reappear recursively. So for each hole in the template, the image will reappear, including the holes in the template for repeatedly smaller images.

Comment: @trichoplax Hmmm, okay. I should give this a lot of thought then. I do think that with the amount of possible ways to approach this problem, this should be a popularity contest. But it's definitely too broad at this stage.

Answer (score 4):

### Temperature in a line of rooms

You have a line of rooms that are different temperatures.

```
      1       2       3  
 1.2  |  3.5  |  4.0  |  3.7
```

The doors between adjacent rooms start out closed. When you open a door, the now-connected rooms average out their temperatures. For example, opening door 2 gives

```
      1       2       3   
 1.2  |  3.75 _  3.75  |  3.7
```

Then, opening door 1 equalizes the first three rooms to their average (1.2+3.75+3.75)/3 = 2.9

```
      1       2       3   
 2.9  _  2.9 _  2.9  |  3.7
```

Finally, if we close door 2 and then open door 3, the last two rooms will average out without affecting the other rooms.

```
      1       2       3   
 2.9  _  2.9 |  3.3  _  3.3
```

You can think of the instructions to open and close doors as a sequence of toggles that switch between open and closed, here `2, 1, 2, 3`, with the doors starting closed. Given the initial temperatures of the rooms and the sequence of door toggles, output the final temperatures. Fewest bytes wins.

**Input:**

- A list of initial room temperatures, which are positive reals. There will be at least two rooms.
- (Optional) The number of rooms n.
- A list of doors to toggle in order, which range from 1 to `n-1`. Optionally, these may be zero-indexed.

**Output:** The list of final room temperatures to some reasonable precision.

TODO: Test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## Senior Prank

We're graduating to a full site soon, and there's only one thing left to do before graduation: pull a senior prank! I think we should do a variation on the classic "fill a hallway with cups of water" gag.

### Challenge

Your program will read in text and output that text, covered in upside-down cups of water. An upside-down cup of water looks like this: `/~\`
These cups can only be placed in whitespace in the input, and can only be placed so that all three characters of the cup are directly above a non-whitespace character (otherwise the water would spill out!). Cups cannot be stacked on top of other cups. Cups must be placed in every available opening, and it is assumed that every input is surrounded by an infinite field of whitespace.
We need to pull the prank off quickly and without anyone noticing, so fewest bytes in each language wins.

### Test Cases

Input:

```
     ____________________________________________
    /   ___    /   ___    /   ______/   ________/
   /   /__/   /   /__/   /   /     /   /_______
  /   _______/   _______/   /     /   //__    /
 /   /      /   /      /   /_____/   /___/   /
/___/      /___/      /_________/___________/
```

Output:

```
     /~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\
     ____________________________________________
    /   ___    /   ___    /   ______/   ________/
   /   /__//~\/   /__//~\/   /     /   /_______
  /   _______/   _______/   //~\  /   //__    /
 //~\/      //~\/      //~\/_____//~\/___//~\/
/___/      /___/      /_________/___________/
```

Input:

```
 L
LOL  ROFL:ROFL:LOL:ROFL:ROFL
 L\\        ____I____
    ========    |  |[\
            \___O==___)
            ___I_I__/
```

Output:

```
 L   /~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\/~\
LOL  ROFL:ROFL:LOL:ROFL:ROFL
 L\\/~\/~\  ____I____
    ========/~\ |  |[\
            \___O==___)
            ___I_I__/
```

Comment: @TimmyD Initially that gap was two wide. I must have added the space after making the output.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yeah, that's a typo. I should really double check when I edit on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

## Create an Autostereogram (Optical Illusion w/ Hidden 3D Shape)

An [autostereogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram) is a type of optical illusion requiring the viewer to, simply put, change distance at which your eyes are trying to view the image. In order to see the hidden image rather than just a nonsensical two-dimensional image, the viewer must either focus their eyes in front of the image (cross-eyed), or behind the image (wall-eyed). Depending on its type, autostereograms may be viewed either way, only cross-eyed, or only wall-eyed. Wall-eyed are the most common.

The illusion below taken from the linked Wikipedia article may only be viewed successfully using the wall-eyed technique. Viewing the full-sized image may help.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Stereogram_Tut_Shark.png]

The hidden image is:

> A shark

I didn't know they were called autostereograms until today, but I always liked this type of optical illusion, since I found the hidden image easy to spot using the wall-eyed technique.

Your goal is to take a depth map and either:

1. Take in an image to modify with the map, then return/display the resulting image
2. Create a random dot autostereogram

The quality of the image must be such that the image is hidden and can be viewed using one of the techniques listed above.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Comment: I've also seen reddit.com/r/crossview which is a similar idea but uses 2 images next to each other to make it look 3d.

Comment: I'd like input on whether people would prefer a [popularity-contest] or [code-golf] for this. I'm not sure if answers would be unique enough for a popularity contest. How much quality will users drop for saving bytes?

Comment: I would clearly go for [tag:code-golf] and restrict it to random dot autostereogram (which e.g. also needs e.g. the number of points as input). This can be defined quite well. (In a popularity contest people would probably just vote what they can see easily. Furthermore the there would be the question about a validity criterion.) I totally like the idea!

Comment: @flawr The thing is, I actually think random dot ones are much harder when trying to view the hidden image.

Comment: @mbomb007 Harder to view or harder to produce? (PS: http://tx.technion.ac.il/~yonie/stereogram.txt)

What do you think about ASCII stereograms? It would be quite a bit easier to make a validity criterion.

Comment: From [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28937828#28937828), it seems like the consensus is that this question should be narrowed. This could potentially become 3 different questions about autostereograms: using random dots, using an image, and using ASCII. I think I'd like to start with using an image, since its output is easily viewable.

Comment: @flawr Do you think other languages would be able to do what Mathematica can? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57108/35531

Comment: Probably, but the mathemtica version is already quite long, and most other languages will probably need way more code to do the same, which, so I'm afraid, could deter many people from participating.

Comment: @flawr Well, it's not golfed yet.

Answer (score 4):

### Golf all the 16 logic gates with 2 inputs and 1 output!

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82938/golf-all-the-16-logic-gates-with-2-inputs-and-1-output) asked for 16 independent functions. I would like the opposite: a single function that takes an additional parameter that specifies which of the 16 logic gates is required using an integer from 0 to 15. If you don't want to use a 0-based index of the list in the linked question then you should specify which integers map to which logic gate (but they should still be 0 to 15).

Examples:

```
 0,0,0  falsey
 1,0,1  falsey
 2,1,0  truthy
 3,1,1  truthy
 4,1,1  falsey
 5,0,1  truthy
 6,1,0  truthy
 7,0,0  falsey
 8,0,0  truthy
 9,0,1  falsey
10,1,0  truthy
11,1,1  truthy
12,1,1  falsey
13,0,1  truthy
14,1,0  truthy
15,0,0  truthy
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Here you go](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12103/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor That one is a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: @Mego How is generating `0101010101010101\n0011001100110011\n0000111100001111\n0000000011111111` the same as golfing 16 logic gates?

Comment: You may want to ban builtins. J has a two-byte solution, `b.`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ How do I go about looking up what `b.` means?

Comment: @Neil [Voila](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotn.htm)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks, I can see that excluding builtins will be necessary. (Strictly speaking, I asked how to look it up, rather than for a direct link, which wouldn't help me look up any other J code should I need to for any reason.)

Comment: @Neil J is a hard language reverse. I would postix your search on google with `site:jsoftware.com`

Answer (score 4):

**Fireworks** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)  [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

---

Make me some fireworks !
And since we are super-late for the 4th make them as quick (read short) as possible !

**Input**
2 integer, the fuse (any value equal or bigger than 5) and the radius (1 - 2 - 3).

The fuse define the lenght of the tail, the last character of the tail is the center of the explosion. The tail must be centered with the explosion.
The radius define the explosion.

**Rule**
No need for exception handling, the input will be a valid one.
You may or may not padd your firework, the choice is up to you.
Input, Output and the choice beetwen full program or function is, once again, up To you and your lenguage of choice.
Standard loophole rules apply.
Hopefully no built-in (i'm looking at you mathematica) exist.

**Example**

```
fuse 5, radius 1  
     * *    
    * * *
     *|*
      |
      |
      |


fuse 10, radius 3  

   *     *
    *   *
     * *    
* * * * * * *
     *|*
    * | *
   *  |  *
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
```

---

while stretching the fuse is not a big deal, ence no limit to it, I found interesting see if it's gonna be cheaper to have hardcoded the strings for the part where the firework cross the fuse or is gonna be cheaper some fancy algorithm, ence I' ve set a limited number of alternative for the radius.

I'm really sorry if my english is bad, I usually can get my idea trought but more than often i stumble with some verbs.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thanks for using the sandbox! "Number" isn't very descriptive, I assume that the fuse and radius should be positive integers (i.e. not including zero)? What happens if the radius is larger than the fuse?

Comment: thanks for the welcome, i'm actually lurking since a bit, but never had something new \ better golfed to add. anyway 2 time my bad :/ . First with the number (i'm used to deal alot with database where number make sense) and then i must have forgot about min and max value while rewriting my question. edited !

Answer (score 4):

## Peter Piper and the Peck of Pickled Peppers

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

---

Without an introduction, output the following tongue twister:

```
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.
A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
```

with or without a trailing newline.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: I did some searching for duplicates, I came up with: [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/39752/31625) and [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34663/31625). There were a couple others that were also rather similar (slim shady and old macdonald), but they had a source restriction or some input as well. I'm not sure if any of them are duplicates, but these seem awfully close.

Comment: I wish the words didn't come in the same chunks. The substrings "Peter Piper picked" and "peck of pickled peppers" are most of the text, and the rest has little structure: `X a Y.
A Y X.
If X a Y,
Where's the Y X?` Is there another tongue-twister where the words are permuted more?

Answer (score 4):

## Transpose a Ragged Array

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given an array of arrays of integers where the rows **may not be of equal length**, pad those rows with nulls, and transpose the array.

**Rules**

- Use any sane input for the array.
- Specify which null(s) you are using for this function.
- The output should be a transposed array, printed in whatever way is sane for your language.
- This is code golf. Aim for the shortest code possible.

**Test cases**

```
I: [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]          # Padding with nil here
O: [[1, 3, 4], [2, nil, 5]]

I: [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
O: [[1, 2, 4], [nil, 3, 5]]

I: [[1, 4, 5], [8, 3, 2], [1, 7, 9, 6]]
O: [[1, 8, 1], [4, 3, 7], [5, 2, 9], [nil, nil, 6]]

I: [[1], [2]]
O: [[1, 2]]

I: [[1, 2]]
O: [[1], [2]]

I: [[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]                  # Padding with spaces here
O: [[4, 8], [5, 9], [6, ' '], [7, ' ']]    # as an example of a different null
```

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: Having arrays that contain both integers and strings seems odd (and unrelated to the challenge) to me.

Comment: @NathanMerrill In my head, I was trying to allow as many nulls as possible by restricting what data the arrays would have. You're right, though, and I have removed the reference to numbers and strings.

Comment: There's still a test case with it :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill That's because I still want arrays that can contain any data.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Alright I rewrote the test case

Comment: Perhaps "ragged" is a better term for "uneven"

Comment: Does the "null" have to be constant or can it depend on the input?

Comment: @Dennis, I think the nulls should be constant for all inputs.

Answer (score 4):

## Insert Random Squares Here

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

<sup>[Related challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output+random).</sup>

< Insert sales pitch here >

### The Challenge

Given a width and a height, output an image filled with random squares.

### Input

Your program/function is given a width and a height in pixels.

E.g.:

```
yourProgram <width> <height>
```

### Output

You must display the result on the screen, or output an image file in [any acceptable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/13486).

### Rules

- The number of squares to be generated is a random natural number between `sqrt(w * h) / 2` and `sqrt(w * h) * 2` (inclusive).
- Each square's color will be randomly generated for each with *R*, *G*, *B* ranging from 0-255 and with *alpha* values ranging from 1-255.
- Each square's width/height will be a random value between `1` and `min(w, h)` (inclusive)
- Each square must be placed randomly. Part of the square may be outside the output image, as long as at least one pixel of the square is visible.

  - Placement at sub-pixel coordinates  (e.g. x=0.239420, y=2.8298329) is allowed but not required.
- Each possible output must be equally likely to occur.
- The output must have a white or transparent background.

### Example

#### Input and randomly generated parameters

```
Width: 10
Height: 20

Maximum square height: 10

Minimum number of squares: 8 Math.sqrt(10*20)/2 = 7.0710678118654755
Maximum number of squares: 28 Math.sqrt(10*20)*2 = 28.284271247461902

Number of squares  in this example: 8
```

#### Output

[image]

Scaled 2000%:
[image]

#### Output with the parts of the squares that are off-screen

(Scaled 2000%.) The gray part is the part that is displayed on the screen.

[image]

Comment: does the background have to be transparent, or can it be a constant color?

Comment: @dzaima I guess the "transparent" doesn't make sense if there is nothing behind the background. A better question is: Must the background be white?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork That's kind of what I meant to say with "Each possible output must be equally likely to occur". Think it needs clarification?

Comment: @dzaima Clarified

Comment: @user202729 Updated the rules to say the output must have a white or transparent background

Comment: Ah, I had understood the "each possible output equally likely" to mean the *positioning* of the squares themselves, rather than a comment on the *entirety* of the random possibilities. Maybe just expanding that bullet point to read something like "The squares' number, color, size, and position must all be equally likely to occur" or similar wording.

Answer (score 4):

## Play a 1D chess variant

in this [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, you must create a bot that plays a 1d [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) variant I created, featuring all leaper pieces, and a 15 long board.

#### Esolangs are encouraged to participate

### Game Rules

#### Goal

To capture the opponents royal (king/queen).

#### Board

The board is 15 squares long

```
Player _______________________________ Player
 one   |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|   two
       player1 side       player2 side
```

Each player has their side of the board. (note that while playing, you will always be on the left side of the board). You have six squares that belong to you, the opponent has six of their squares, and three squares in the middle are unowned.

**Setting up**

At the start of the game, you will place your pieces into a configuration of your choice. The pieces will be set independently of each other; this game does not have perfect information. When setting up, you will pick where to place your four pieces, and whether they will be reversed (see next section). You may only place your pieces in your owned squares.

#### Pieces

There are 4 / 8 pieces; there are 4 distinct pieces, which you can have reversed, and unreversed. I have given them distinct names. Their movements are detailed here.

***reversed***

reversed means that all the moves of these pieces are reversed in their direction; 2 forward becomes 2 back, three back becomes three forward.

Capture means to move to a space occupied by an enemy piece, and remove that piece from the game.
Move means to move to a space occupied by no pieces.

Ascii "diagrams" have been provided. P denotes the piece being showed, $ denotes a space the piece can move to, X a place the piece can capture on, # a piece can move and capture on. Diagrams are the same for both pieces in a pair, because one simply executes the moves backwards.

#### ***You must have exactly 4 pieces on the board, and have exactly one from each of the pairs below.***

**Footman (f)/Coward (c)**

The footman may move to an empty space one (1) forward, and capture two (2) forward.

The coward may move to an empty space one (1) backward, and capture two (2) backward.

```
P$X
```

**Horse (h)/spider (s)**

The horse may move to an empty space two (2) or three (3) forward, and move or capture one (1) backward.

The spider may move to an empty space two (2) or three (3) backward, and move or capture one (1) forward.

```
#P $$
```

**Archer (a)/Trickster (t)**

(I doubt anyone will use trickster unironically)

The archer may move two (2) squares backward, one (1) forward, and may capture four (4) steps forward

The trickster may move two (2) squares forward, one (1) backward, and may capture four (4) steps backward

I have included some black and white squares for clarity in distance

```
# # # #
$ P$  X
```

**King (k)/Queen (q)**

Both Royal pieces will end the game when captured.

The king may move or capture one (1) backward

The queen may move or capture one (1) forward

```
#P
```

#### Misc.

Check does not exist: Royal pieces may be left en prise, capture of them results in a win for the capturing side.

There is no (pawn) promotion of any kind

A piece may not attempt to move of the board; the board is a fixed size and does not wrap.

### Programs

Programs will take input. When they take input of "0", or a specific input of your choosing, they will output a setup for the game.
when they take input "1", or a specific input of your choosing, they will then receive input of the board, and output a move. (the program will be run multiple times)

#### Moving

To move, you will output the square that the piece is currently on, and the space where you wish to move the piece to, or have the piece capture on. The format is as so (in regex):

```
[0-9a-e]\n?[0-9a-e]\n?
```

The board is zero indexed, a piece on the first square is on square 0.

There should be exactly 2 non-newline characters in the output

#### Input

when it is your turn to move, you will receive input. The input you receive will represent the pieces in the playing field. The input will fit the regex here:

```
[fFcChHsSaAtTkKqQ ]{15}
```

Caps represent enemy pieces, lowercase represent your pieces.

when you receive the board positions, you will always have the perspective of player one

## WIP, will do more later

## Sandbox

What should happen if bots enter an infinite loop? I could just make a draw on a time limit, but that seems not so great, since it is hard for bots to know when they are doing this.

Also just other feedback in general

Comment: Maybe put the ASCII characters used to represent the pieces next to each description so we know what each piece is? It looks pretty vague right now. Also, the king and queen together seems redundant - maybe have it *one or the other*?

Comment: 1. The solution to infinite loops would seem to be automatic draw on three-fold repetition. 2. Is the Nash equilibrium pure or mixed?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Three-fold repetition== one repetition of position (if bots have no RNG/are determistic, and I don't want non-RNG bots to suffer), and the bots don't know when they are repeating, because they have no memory. I was kind of thinking of maybe removing a square or something, but that would kind of mess up some stuff... I kind of want to introduce some aspects that will change the position, like adding a piece or something. 2. I imagine you are talking about the starting positions, given perfect play. I have no idea, but it's probably an intricate Rock Paper Scissors cycle

Comment: When I asked about the Nash equilibrium I'd calculated that the number of starting positions is only a bit over 5000 each, so I thought it would be practical to brute-force. But the number of board positions is quite a bit higher, so it's probably not very practical without spending a lot of money. I'm not going to try writing a game tree searcher tonight to verify that. Re repetition: normally in koth you want to use persistent processes where possible, because otherwise the overhead of launching the program for every single move makes it *really* slow to score.

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe I would make the time it takes to win factor into the score, so that riskier strategies can do as well as a perfectly planned program might; It would make a more diverse series of strategies

Comment: Is there a limit on how long a turn can take? IMO the obvious solution is a minimax tree, so we'd need to know about how many turns we can look ahead.

Answer (score 4):

## Generate a Call Tree [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Given a C program, generate a graphical call tree.

A call tree is a tree where the nodes represent stack frames, and the connections represent nested function calls. For example, here is a simple C program and its call tree:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() {
    return 4;
}

int bar(int a) {
    return a + 2;
}

int baz(int a, int b) {
    return a + foo() + bar(a)*bar(b);
}

int main() {
    int a = baz(1, 2);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: call tree]

### Layout

The layout of a call tree is as follows:

- The top function is always `main()`.
- On the next level below are all of the functions that `main` calls, in order of calling (top-to-bottom, left-to-right).
- On the next level are all of the functions that those functions call, and so on.
- The leaves of the tree are functions which do not call other functions, or are standard library functions (which are treated as black boxes).
- Each function (with its argument list) is in a rectangle, large enough that the function name and argument list isn't touching the rectangle's borders.
- Rectangles must not touch other rectangles.
- The lines drawn between the rectangles must not touch or cross any line or rectangle other than the two rectangles they are connecting.
- The text must be a monospaced 14-point font.
- The colors of the text, rectangles, lines, and background are not important, so long as all text is one color, all rectangles are one color, all lines are one color, the background is a single color, and everything can be clearly distinguished from the background.

Note that the example image above does not perfectly follow these rules.

## Rules

- You may assume that the C program is a valid, standalone program (all functions called are either defined in the input source code or exist in an `#include`d header, and no input is taken from any source).
- Any functions not defined in the input source code are assumed to not call any other functions (this is not the case in reality, but it allows for simplification of the call trees, namely by avoiding implementation-specific details)
- All function calls in the call tree must include the arguments passed.
- `main` is assumed to not have any arguments.
- There will be no function pointers, `goto`s, `setjmp`/`jonglmp` calls, dynamic memory allocation/deallocation (so no `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` or `free`), or preprocessor macros in the input source code.
- There will be no infinite loops or infinite recursion (all programs are guaranteed to terminate and thus have a finite call tree).
- All arguments will be `int`s (to simplify matters, since the types don't really matter for this challenge). This means that the example program above would not be a valid input, because of the `printf` call.
- All functions will either return an `int` or will be `void` (non-returning) functions.

Comment: What about recursion? Do we have to support the full complexity of the C grammar?

Comment: @orlp Clarified on recursion as well as loops. Are there any parts of the C grammar that would be problematic, in your opinion?

Comment: Mainly that [the actual grammar](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) is quite large.

Comment: @orlp For the most part, a lot of it can be ignored, because it won't have anything to do with function calls. Solutions will still be larger than typical code golf solutions, but that's fine - not every code golf challenge needs a 10-or-less-bytes solution.

Comment: It is implied that the text in the nodes should include a representation of the arguments, but what should that representation be when they aren't "nice" ones like integers or strings? Obvious nasty cases are structs, unions, and pointers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point. I'll restrict it to ints.

Comment: Is it possible that the source will contain function declarations (as opposed to function definitions)? Those can look a lot like function calls (especially if they appear inside functions, which is legal in C).

Comment: @ais523 Yes, they are allowed. They don't look that similar to function calls - function calls don't have a type signature prefixed (`foo();` versus `int foo();`).

Comment: What about code of the form `a * foo();`? That's either a function call or a function declaration depending on whether `a` is a type or a variable. (You could probably get around this by banning pointers full stop, not just function pointers.)

Comment: @ais523 I clarified that all functions will either return `int` or `void`, so that won't be an issue. Besides, you can't declare a variable that has the same name as a type, so that situation could be deterministically resolved without the restriction.

Comment: I like the idea of the challenge a lot, but I'm not convince that the "graphical output" part adds something... I think just printing it one call per line, and increasing the indentation level would be enough.

Comment: Also, what about if there is a function call like `f(f(n))` ? Should we consider that a call to `f(1)` is done first, then a call to `f(result of f(1))`? (maybe adding a line about it would be nice)

Comment: @Dada Re: [tag:graphical-output]: it's a lot harder to have an unambiguous, readable tree in text format versus graphical format. RE; nested calls, yes, nested calls are evaluated left-to-right, starting with the innermost nest and working outwards. For example, `int main() { f(a(), b(c())); return 0;}` would be `main [ a, c, b, f ]` (see what I mean about unambiguous and readble format for text?).

Comment: @Mego If you ask for a text format version based on indentation, I don't think there can be any ambiguity. But if you prefer graphical-output, why not (I just think that most of the code will be about formatting the graphical output, while I find the "genrate the call tree" part more interesting, but that's only my personal opinion, I like the challenge either way).

Answer (score 4):

## Golf the truth and null values

In many programming languages there is a null and/or other special values. Sometimes they don't follow the normal rules of boolean operations. They may not even agree with the values of the same name in other languages.

Here are some different kinds of the "extended" boolean values, either borrowed from some languages or invented myself:

- `F`alse.
- `T`rue.
- `A`bsent. All operations between absent and another operand return the other operand.
- `W`hatever. All operations between whatever and another operand returns whatever (itself).
- `P`artial. If the result can be decided using the other operand, return that. Otherwise return partial (itself).
- `E`rror. An error as the first operand works like whatever, and an error as the second operand works like partial, except that "itself" means error. It has higher precedence than whatever and partial.

Your task is to define all these values in your language, and the 2 operations `and` `or`.

To be clear, the 2 operations should work exactly as in the following tables. The left column represents the first operand, and the top row the second operand.

```
and F T A W P E       or F T A W P E
  F F F F W F F        F F T F W P E
  T F T T W P E        T T T T W T T
  A F T A W P E        A F T A W P E
  W W W W W W W        W W W W W W W
  P F P P W P E        P P T P W P E
  E E E E E E E        E E E E E E E
```

### Rules

You could use anything [distinct and consistent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10885/25180) to represent these values. You don't have to use a truthy value to represent true, or a falsy value to represent false. You are allowed and encouraged to use values that contain useful code, i.e. [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/25180) is not forbidden.

You are allowed to use actual errors or exceptions to represent some of the values. In this case the definition of that value should throw the same error, instead of represent the caught error. But the caught errors or the output messages should be distinct and consistent. Alternatively, you may choose to include STDERR in the output of your code, and use the printed message string as a normal value.

You may choose to pass functions generating and returning the values but doing nothing else to your code as input, in place of the values themselves, without counting the extra code.

You may use different ways of input/output for different values, as long as it is consistent for each kind of value, and it is possible to tell apart the first and the second operand.

You are allowed to use builtin functions and operators without boilerplate, in any argument order, even if you cannot save them in something callable in your language.

There could be some common code shared by all the 8 definitions and appear only once as header/footer. Other than that, the 8 definitions of operations and values must work independently from each other. The only way you can call something defined in the values in the operations is through a valid input method (e.g. you cannot set a variable in a value and read it in an operation).

Your score is the length of common code * 12 + the total length of the 2 operations * 6 + the total length of the values. Smallest score wins. The length of a value is either the length of the code generating it, or the length of itself unquoted if all the values are strings and you choose this way.

---

### Abandoned rules

You are allowed to use operators, or chains of operators and values to represent the 2 operations, even if you cannot save them in something callable in your language. You may require the operands to appear at specific positions, but each operand must appear exactly once and be grouped together. You may choose whether to save operands in variables previously, and don't count the assignment if it doesn't add new information in the assignment (e.g. by changing its type). This makes it possible to use the built-in operators with short-circuit evaluation in languages that don't allow redefining them and preserve this characteristic, and may also make it shorter in some other languages.

Previous scoring: total length of the 2 operations * 50 + the total length of the values.

### Possible follow-up

Original title: All the weirdness about the nulls

Extended tables including `V`alid in a previous version, `R`everse aka Opposite by Zgarb, and `P`ossible.

```
and T F N O W E V R P     or T F N O W E V R P
  T T F T O W E ? F T      T T T T T W T T T T
  F F F F F W F F F F      F T F F O W E ? T F
  N T F N O W E ? ? ?      N T F N O W E ? ? ?
  O O F O O W E ? O O      O T O O O W E ? O T
  W W W W W W W ? W W      W W W W W W W ? W W
  E E E E E E E ? E E      E E E E E E E ? E E
  V T F ? O F F ? ? ?      V T T ? T F F ? T ?
  R F F ? O W ? ? ? ?      R T T ? O W ? ? ? ?
  P T F ? O W ? ? ? ?      P T F ? T W ? ? ? ?
```

Other potential additions:

- Default, that is opposite to Opposite.
- Merge Possible with Valid.

### Sandbox questions

1. Will this be too easy in some languages that already have all of them?

   In languages that has True defined to be -1 and unifies bitwise and logical operations, most integers would works as `P`artial. GCD/LCM in APL is similar to this. SQL null is <del>`W`hatever</del> `P`artial. Most languages that has shortcut evaluation has errors as `E`rror. Not sure about `A`bsent, though.

   (Maybe the easiest way to find out is to post this question. It doesn't make the answer bad. But it's just some consideration in the sandbox for me to decide whether I'll post a stronger version.)
2. Allowing "operators and chains of operators" seems to open a can of worms. Should I just remove this rule?

Comment: How about `Opposite` that behaves like the negation of the other operand?

Comment: @Zgarb Too similar to `Other`. For the "2 more to be added", I intended to make it possible to write expressions to 1) decide whether a variable is a specific value, and 2) return a specific value if a variable is true, or false otherwise. This may make the list more useful later.

Comment: @Zgarb I gave up and even removed one, to make hardcoding the tables less likely to be the optimal way.

Comment: `if(whatever){/*???*/}`

Comment: @Zgarb I forgot this post for some reasons. Now I found your idea quite interesting. But I'll post the first version without it, and may add a stronger version if it worked well or is too easy, and may name it Degenerate to make most of the other results from operations make sense.

Answer (score 4):

## Machines learning arithmetic

**Note: Feel free to take and use this challenge, either the entire challenge as is, or just parts of it.**

<sub>I've made a complete rewrite of this question. I figured the original version was more complex than it had to be. The task is essentially the same. The original challenge text had 4 upvotes and can be found in the edit history.</sub>

---

You will receive 30 lists of integers. Those lists are the result of a polynomial expression `y = p(x) = a*x^4 + b*x^3 + c*x^2 + d*x + e`, for `x` in the inclusive range `[-1e5, 1e5]`. Let's call those lists `L1, L2 ...`.

I reserve the right to make changes to the lists by changing constants and the order if solutions seem to be custom made for those 30 lists.

**Challenge:**

Your task is to figure out what the constants `a, b, c, d, e` are for each of those 30 lists.

You will write a code that pulls numbers from each list (one list at a time). It must ask for the `y`-values for individual `x`-values, as many as you want, but one at a time. When you think you have enough information, you'll attempt to guess the value of the constants.

You'll do this for all 30 lists.

### Scoring:

The lowest score wins!

- You get **1** point for every number you pull from the list
- You get **10** points for every attempt to crack the code (guess `a, b, c, d, e`)
- The scores for all lists will be added up.

If no submission cracks all lists successfully then the one that cracked the most will win. Tie breaker #1 will be fewest points, tie breaker #2 will be time of submission.

### Rules and clarifications:

You can assume all constants to be integers

The lists will be formatted in this way (suppose the expression for `L1` is: `2*x`). I'm using MATLAB/Octave syntax for a cell array. You can change this to fit your needs (language).

```
L1 = {[-200000, -199998, -199996, ... -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, ... 199996, 199998, 200000], [0 0 0 2 0]};
```

You can change the format to fit your needs, but you must not mix the list and the values for `a, b, c, d, e`.

### Example:

You ask for `y` for four different input values, and get the results:

```
L1(0) = 0
L1(1) = 0
L1(2) = 2
L1(3) = 12
```

Your function guesses (for some reason) that this is `x^3-2x^2+1`, and attempts to crack it:

```
L1([0, 1, -2, 0, 1]
false
```

You have tried 4 values, and attempted to crack it once. This gives you `4 + 10 = 14 points`.

You try a few more values:

```
L1(-9) = 6480
L1(-7) = 2352
L1(7)  = 2352
L1(9)  = 6480
L1(100)= 99990000
```

You're now confident that this has to be: `x^4-x^2`, and attempt to crack it again:

```
f([1 0 -1 0 0])
true
```

You have successfully guessed the constants `a, b, c, d, e`, and get a score of `14 + (5 + 10) = 29 points.

You have 29 functions left.

---

- I'll have to post the lists on some suitable place (where)?
- Can I ban builtin interpolation functions somehow without risking the "unobservable requirements", "x without y" pitfalls?
- Anything else?

Comment: This isn't yet 100% clear to me, but I've upvoted because it looks like an interesting idea that will make a great challenge once fine tuned.

Comment: :) Anything in particular that isn't clear, or everything in general?

Comment: I've edited... It was never intentional to have the number of bytes mixed in here... I'm probably just so used to writing it that I didn't even notice it :P

Comment: Will it be done like: 1. "start writing your function" 2. "end of function writing period" 3. "release black box function for scoring submissions"? To avoid learning the expressions and tuning the functions to fit.

Comment: I guess you could have a controller that generates new random test cases each time to allow the competition to be open ended, but rescoring the old entries might reorder them in some cases. Might need to average over a number of different sets of test cases.

Comment: The given example of `h(x) = ((3*x*x*x)/(x+1))+1` is incompatible with "*You can assume the functions will give integer results back*". But basically it's a case of guessing and verifying a rational function of some bounded degree?

Comment: If you want a variety of languages to be able to compete without having to implement arbitrary size integer arithmetic, you could use modular arithmetic. For example, everything is mod 256, or 65536.

Comment: @Emigna, good question :) One solution could be: Provide x number of functions on a certain format. After the submission is posted it will be tested against the "real" cases that are of similar difficulty, but different. I think I can have some fairly easy, and some quite hard. But it's a really good question, so I'm not sure... I'm open for ideas :)

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I made a blooper when making the examples. Using rational functions with input arguments and 8/10(?) significant figures in the output is probably a good idea. I think 10 is low enough that rounding shouldn't be an issue as long as you have the correct function..? And it can be restricted to 3/4/5..9th degree polynomials.

Comment: Peter's comment also makes me wonder what happens for division by zero. Will this be avoided somehow or will we be informed that a particular input causes an error? Will the error be specifically "division by zero" or just "error"?

Comment: First comment @trichoplax: You have a point, but it will also make it harder, since it will no longer be a continuous function. Second comment: I think an error message / warning of some sort would suffice. Handling that error should be very simple, since this isn't code golf. It will probably be 1-3 lines of code. Giving `inf` for divison by zero, and error for `0/0` could also be a solution (that's the default solution in MATLAB).

Comment: Note that if you want continuous functions you would need to avoid rational functions, but it sounds like you're happy with piecewise continuous if you don't mind "inf" and "error" in some places?

Comment: @trichoplax, What do you think? Is modular arithmetic a good idea? Should I skip division (impossible to avoid division by zero if not)?

Comment: I really don't know. I'm just suggesting possibilities. Someone more mathematical would probably be useful for assessing whether modular and rational functions would be interesting to crack. Are you aiming for a situation where most people can write code that cracks all 10, but getting a low score is challenging, or where most people can only crack a proportion of the 10?

Comment: It's not impossible to avoid division by zero. If you have a rational polynomial `p(x) / q(x)` where `q`'s zeros are not integers, you're fine. Just need to arrange for the test cases to have denominators with complex or non-rational real zeros.

Comment: This could be a cop's and robber's type game?

Comment: Parentheses should be removed since it makes this challenge much more difficult... and it is already really difficult without them

Comment: "Can this be done": Yes, This is basically a challenge about interpolation with as few reference points as possible.

Comment: I've realized that too. The idea was first to require that people actually figured out the exact expression, but I figured that would be too hard.

Comment: The new text is much better, and seems much more concrete to me.  That said, I'm no math expert, but I feel like the optimal solution is something that is probably already widely known, which means you'll have a bunch of submissions with the same score, or worse, a bunch of submissions that are optimized towards your set of lists (even a slight optimization makes a difference).

Comment: I'm not sure whether you or someone else had a separate answer with essentially the same challenge, but I have a definite sense of déjà vu in pointing out that it's very similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84779/194

Comment: Found it: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11343/194 . IMO you should delete one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

## Regex Golf Generators

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex)

### Challenge:

#### Cops:

The cops must post a 150 byte or less program in any language that outputs between 20 and 200 strings of printable ASCII (this excludes newlines), half of them "match" strings and half "don't match" strings. You can't output an odd number of strings -- there must be one don't match for each match.

The strings can be output as two lists of strings, or one list with a fixed delimiter between the "match" and "don't match" sections. The "match" and "don't match" lists can come in any order.

The following special characters are not allowed in the strings: `()[]*+?.\|^$`.

Note that the program must be deterministic, and the language must be revealed.

#### Robbers:

The robbers must pick a cop answer and submit a regex in any flavor  that matches the "match" strings but does not match the "don't match" strings.

The regex must be shorter than `min(<length of all the match strings> + <number of match strings>-1 + 4, <length of all the don't match strings> + <number of don't match strings>-1 + 10)`, as this is the length of the regex that simply hardcodes it: `^(<match string 1>|<match string 2>|...)$` or `^(?!(<don't match string 1>|<don't match string 2>|...)$).*`.

The shortest regex posted for that submission wins (note that there can and should be multiple competing cracks for one submission).

### Scoring:

The robber's score is simply their number of wins (posted the shortest regex for a given submission) -- higher is better.

The cop's score is `max(byte count of winning regex - byte count of submission - 4*(number of match strings - 10) for each submission)` -- again, higher is better (you should be maximizing the length of the cracks and minimizing the length of your code). The byte count of the winning regex for an uncracked submission is the length of the hardcoded regex. Self cracks are permitted but must be marked as non-competing and will not count toward your cop or robber score.

The winning cop and robber will be announced 2 weeks after the posting of this challenge. Submissions will be allowed after that, but will not count towards your score.

Comment: Can they be a list of lists, i.e. `[['string1',truthy],['string2',falsy]...]`? With truthy/falsy being match/don't match.

Comment: I've said this in chat, but I'm listing it here for reference:  1. No need to have a fixed number of match strings. 2. No need to remove regex special characters.  Everybody has the same benefit of using them. 3. No need to have a maximum regex length.  It's like having a maximum bytes on a [tag:code-golf]. 4. I don't see why you want to aggregate the cops' scores.  Simply make it a standard maximum-score-wins.   Otherwise, a person who posted the best scoring submission may lose to another who only posted a single decent submission. 5. Disallow self-cracks.  It's too abusive for robbers.

Comment: What's the point of allowing a "Retina flavor" of regex? Wouldn't that be identical to .NET?

Answer (score 4):

## Me, Me, Me!

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Edit: changed success when the input matches the source code to when the input is any permutation of the source.

Your code is clearly superior to all other code. In fact, your code is so great that it prints itself when the opportunity arises (but not when any other, inferior code is around.)

### Task

Write a program or function that takes a string as input. If the string is equal to some permutation of the characters in your source code, then output the entire source code. Otherwise, output `Gross.`

If your language uses a non-ascii encoding, "character" is defined as whatever a character in your source looks like. If it's unreasonable to take input in that format, you can treat the bytes of your source as their respective extended ascii codes.

### Input

Takes a string using whatever input mechanism your programming language provides.

### Output

Prints either the entire source of your program or the word `Gross.` No additional output is permitted.

### Rules

- You can take input using any reasonable method. (Stdin, function parameter, etc.)
- A string *a* is a permutation of a string *b* iff each character in the alphabet appears the same number of times in *a* and *b*.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) Shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: [tag:quine]? --

Comment: @MDXF it will have the quine tag, of course – but it's not strictly a quine unless it gets the right input! I just didn't see how to add tags in the answer...

Comment: Use `[tag:quine]` in the header. And yes, we accept the [tag:quine] tag for quine variants :-)

Comment: [trivial extension of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant)

Comment: aw shucks. I figured something like this existed already, just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: actually, @DestructibleLemon I could be missing something obvious but I don't think the extension is trivial. Printing its own source code is, I would say, significantly harder than printing "true" as long as I add the usual restriction that it can't read its own source.

Comment: @rogaos If the test on the input passes, printing its source code is as simple as printing the input string.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit true of course, but adding the print statement may make the quine harder to construct in the first place. (Except in languages like javascript, which are basically reading their own source anyway.) Maybe the challenge would be improved by transforming the input string in some way, or crashing on "correct" input?

Comment: @rogaos it is the difference between printing true and printing the input

Comment: modified to use permutations of the input rather than the input itself

Answer (score 4):

## What is your Operating System?

*I can't believe we haven't had this one before*

To avoid any doubts about what constitutes a separate OS, you must return an index into your chosen subset (containing minimum two) of the following OS families. You may order your set as you like, so include your ordered set, and state if you use zero or one based indexing. You may also bunch together families you cannot distinguish between.

Windows, Minix, Linux, macOS, BSD, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Unix, Z/OS, OS/2, QNX

Your score is your byte count divided by the square of the number of indices your code can return – given that it is run on the appropriate OSs, of course.

You do not have to account for virtual machines, emulation layers etc., e.g. WSL and Wine.

#### Examples

Your code can detect Windows, macOS, AIX, and Linux. It returns `0` for Windows, `1` for macOS, `2` for AIX, and `3` for Linux. Your score is a sixteenths of your byte count.

Your code can distinguish between Z/OS, OS/2, and UNIX/Linux/AIX. It returns `1` for Z/OS, `2` for OS/2, and `3` for any UNIX-like OS. Your score is a ninth of your byte count.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: 2 is definitely better than 1. After that I think it may just be your preference for the kinds of answers you want. I think 3 will promote more answers that reach, while 2 will promote more 2 answers. However, if you really want to reach maybe make the denominator grow as a square? These scoring mechanisms are unfortunately very important to these kinds of challenges as well as very hard to figure out beforehand. I'd ask around and see what other people think!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks.

Comment: Are not macOS, BSD, and Linux Unix? Is OSX considered the same as macOS?

Comment: The I/O requirements are rather strict, could you not just print/return the name of the OS?

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes, but you may pick whichever many you want from that list, so you can bunch all Unixes together or keep them separate, or you can detect specific flavors while also detecting vanilla Unix.

Comment: @musicman523 I'd rather have comparable output from all solutions.

Comment: It seems like people with access to proprietary OSs will have an advantage in this problem.  For example, to ensure my code runs on Windows I have to *buy* windows, because I don't own it.  I happen to own a copy of OSX, but other users might not given me an advantage.  I feel like this is problematic. (also is OSX considered the same macOS?)

Comment: @WheatWizard You're right, but that will be problematic in detection of OSs no matter what the challenge is. And yes, good luck testing your solution on Z/OS…

Comment: It's not just that. If I claim to detect Windows, which versions of Windows do I have to test it on? And what can I assume about e.g. the C header files that are available?

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh, and yes, OSX and macOS are the same (I don't expect anyone to submit an answer that will run on MacOS 9-)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point. Any ideas how to fix this or is it doomed?

Comment: I suspect that the difficulties around specification and testing might explain why this hasn't been asked already.

Comment: Why numbers only? Why not just *outputs*?

Comment: Is the set of OSes listed there exhaustive? (I've done some programming on SunOS in the past, for example, although I don't have access to it right now.) Also, "Unix" seems a bit strange to have in the list; many of the listed OSes (e.g. BSD and Solaris) are flavours of Unix. It's also worth being aware of cases like WSL and Wine; which OS should they count as?

Comment: @ais523 "Unix " allows submissions to bunch together various flavors as one, and also allows differentiating the other Unixy OSs from vanilla Unix. I'll add a note about virtual machines etc.

Answer (score 4):

#### Let's play Othello (Reversi)! [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Open for takeover

I don't have the time to devote to this right new, and not for the foreseeable future. Anyone who wants this idea, the post, and any code I have in the repo should comment below.

Side note on the code, I have a gorilla repl file in the repo that I can use to run test games on, and get screenshots of during any point of the game. If you want I can make up screenshots for the rules section since I have everything setup on my end for that.

---

This would be a king of the hill about reversi. Yep. I'm going to write up the post and <s>controller later</s> **The controller is being written here: https://github.com/JJ-Atkinson/reversi-koth-ppcg** , but I'm putting this here so show the idea is taken ;)

---

#### Post start

## Rules

*(you can probbably skip this if you've played Reversi before)*

[image]

(images from http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-reversi)

Reversi is a two player game with a simple goal - own the most pieces on the board.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi)

Comment: You will need a complete set of rules, and some high-level description of the controller (as well as a detailed spec when it's written), and you'll need to work out some victory criteria.

Comment: Yep, all that is in the works. I'll add a questions section when it is ready for review.

Comment: As for a longer title, you could simply do "Let's play Reversi"

Comment: This is not Reversi. This is Othello. [Source](http://worldothello.org/?q=content/reversi-versus-othello). *In Reversi as it was originally played, the starting configuration was not predetermined, like it is in Othello. Players would take turns setting down the first four pieces in the center of the board*

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll keep reversi in the title, since I've always seen this game called reversi.

Comment: @JAtkin But it is not called Reversi. I quote: *Unfortunately, because the games look similar and have similar rules, and “Othello” is a trademark and “Reversi” is not, many board game sellers, websites, software makers, etc., wanted to piggy back on the popularity of Othello by calling their game “Reversi”. Quite aggravatingly, they never use the rules of real Reversi (as far as we've ever seen).* I insist that you remove all instances of Reversi from your post.

Comment: I understand fully that Reversi is _not_ the correct name of this game. However, many people (myself included) _have not heard of Othello, and only know about Reversi, even if our understanding was incorrect._ I plan to keep both names. I think I'll include the article you reference, but I won't remove Reversi. This is not because I dislike being correct, it is because I believe that it brings the tangible benefit of wider recognition and perhaps higher viewership of the post. I will have a strongly defined rules section so any concern about confusion about rules can be dismissed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Simulate Alpha Decay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144160/66833)

Comment: Is output to stderr ignored?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Most likely yes, since this is allowed [by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error/4781#4781).

Answer (score 4):

## [One OEIS after another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133754/66833)

Comment: This sounds fun!

Comment: Awesome frickin' idea. You might wanna add what to do when one answer reaches 289,585 bytes ('cause obscure esolangs). ;)

Comment: @totallyhuman I would've thought that that score is about right for Java, so I'll address that

Comment: A possible problem is that many languages have "add 1" and "subtract 1" or similar functions that are inverses of each other. So you could add any even amount of bytes. For example, sequence A005843 (the even integers) in CJam can be [`ri2*`](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTSOv/f1MA) or [`ri2*()()()()()()()()`](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTSEtDExX@/28KAA)

Comment: Ah, no, the rule is that removing any _subset_ of the characters must give wrong output. That rule is enough to invalidate the above

Comment: I think the rule about the program having to be pristine is bad for this challenge. It makes writing answers incredibly difficult in most languages. Why do you care if people change the length of their post? All they can do is control which sequence appears next.

Comment: You might want to bold or otherwise emphasize `unused language`, as I missed it the first couple times I read through (or just remove that restriction, because it would be more fun if we had to go through all sequences instead of all languages ;) ). Also, what to do about very short sequences, such as [the busy beaver sequence](https://oeis.org/A028444)?

Answer (score 4):

## Invisible Ink, Easy [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In the physical world, invisible ink usually becomes invisible when it dries, and is then is readable if it is exposed to heat or chemicals of some kind. The invisible ink in this challenge will be readable when exposed to highlighting.

Create a full program or function that takes in text from the console (using a prompt) and outputs it the console so it cannot be seen unless highlighted.

[image]

[image]

### Notes:

- Assume that the console is a solid color (black, white, green, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

## Prime encode integers!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In this challenge, you must convert inputted natural numbers into a prime encoding.

The sequence of the primes, and 1, is a complete sequence (We're going to consider 1 an honourary prime for this challenge). What this means is that it's possible to express any positive integer as a sum of the terms of the sequence (without reusing terms). For example, the powers of two are a complete sequence, and you can encode numbers in them (this is binary).

As with binary, you use a sequence of 1s and 0s to represent which terms are used. 1011 will represent 5 + 1 + 2, or 8. 8 could also be represented as 10001, or 7+1. the place values represent primes:

```
... 13 11 7 5 3 2 1
```

continuing with all of the primes to the left

### In this challenge, you must output a string of 1s and 0s, such that the place value primes sum to inputted strictly positive integer

Test cases

```
8 -> 10001 or 1011
2 -> 10
11 -> 1111 or 10101 or 100000 (I might have missed one of the possibilities?)
13 -> 1000000 or any other possibility
```

you may use *any* valid representation of the in

#### input note:

input is 1 strictly positive integer

you do not need to consider the value 0, even though it is possible to represent in this system, by just outputting zero

Comment: I'm assuming input is `n>0`? IO in all normal means? Is this [tag:code-golf]? I'm also assuming we can return any valid combination?

Comment: didn't it specifically say n>0? and also specifically say you can return any valid representation?

Comment: It does specifically say "*strictly positive*", but a long way *after* it says "*inputted integers*". It's best to state restrictions like that as early as possible to avoid misleading or confusing readers.

Answer (score 4):

## Find the longest Factor-Multiple sequence

Inspired by this [riddle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/pick-a-number-any-number/).

A Factor-Multiple sequence is any sequence where **A[n+1]** is either a multiple or factor of **A[n]**.

### Task

Create a full program or function that, given a list (or any other accepted input) of positive integers, returns (one of the) the longest possible Factor-Multiple sequence containing those numbers. Each number can only be used once and each number in the input will be unique.

### Input

As mentioned above, input is a list of integers. If your language only supports strings, or if you like doing so, you may take input as strings instead.

### Output

You can output your sequence in any way you like as defined on meta.

### Rules

- This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf), shortest code wins.

### Test cases

More need to be added.

```
Input                                                Output                 
1 2 3 5 7 11                                         2 1 3 or 3 1 2 or 11 1 7 etc.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10                                 5 10 1 4 8 2 6 3 9  

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20   11  1  7 14  2  8 16  4 12  6 18  9  3 15  5 10 20
```

## Meta:

- Need to add more test-cases
- Can't think of any relevant rules, did I miss any?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44922/194) (same problem, different graph).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the link. From what I can see, that challenge has a one-directional graph, while in this challenge if a is connected to b => b connects to a. I am not sure if that changes the algorithms involved, but it would be interesting to see them golfed.

Comment: Actually the biggest difference is that the other one asks for approximate answers and this one asks for exact answers.

Answer (score 4):

## I'm symmetric, not palindromic! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Background

Inspired by [I'm a palindrome. Are you?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/im-a-palindrome-are-you), where it is presented the [shocking](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/5vkrg5/) fact that “`()()` is not a palindrome, but `())(`”, I asked myself what instead is `()()` and the answer is simply: it is a string with a vertical symmetry axis!

#### The task

Write a program or function that takes a string S (or the appropriate equivalent in your language) as input, checks for symmetry along the vertical axis, and returns a [truthy or falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194) value accordingly. You can use [any reasonable means](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) to take the input and provide the output.

#### Reflectional symmetry

Reflectional symmetry around a vertical axis (or left-right symmetry) means that if you put a mirror vertically at the exact center of the string, the reflected image of the first half of the string is identical to the second half of the string.

For example, the following strings are reflectional symmetric around a vertical axis:

```
()()
()()()
[A + A]
WOW ! WOW
OH-AH_wx'xw_HA-HO
(<<[[[T*T]]]>>)
(:)
)-(
())(()
qpqp
```

while the following are not:

```
())(
((B))
11
+-*+-
WOW ! wow
(;)
qppq
```

#### Rules of the contest

• Your program or function will receive only printable ASCII characters. You can include or not the empty string, (which is symmetric, of course!) as legal input, which is better for you.

• The ASCII characters that can be considered symmetric with respect to the vertical axes are the following (note the initial space, and the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters):

```
 !"'+*-.:=AHIMOTUVWXY^_ovwx|
```

The ASCII characters that can be considered “mirrored” and their corresponding characters are:

```
()<>[]{}qpbd/\
```

Note that, since they are mirrored, you can have both `()` as well as `)(`, `/\` and `\/`, etc.

All the other ASCII printable characters must be considered asymmetric and without a mirrored corresponding character.

• This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge: the shorter your program is, measured in bytes, the better, in any programming language.

• Kudos to people that will produce a symmetric program!

Comment: You seem to be missing two pairs of mirror-able characters: `qpdb`. Also, I'm not sure about the mixed-win criteria: "this is code-golf ...but I will mark as accepted the shortest symmetric program, if there will be at least one!", I'd go for "imaginary brownies" or just "kudos" (let the upvotes or bounties reward).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JonathanAllan, I will correct the text about mirrored characters, and the criteria for winning.

Comment: This question is very confusing, because the string it gives as an example of vertical symmetry is actually vertically symmetric, but the *definition* it gives of vertical symmetry is actually the definition of *horizontal* symmetry.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, my definition is in accord with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(geometry)#Reflectional_symmetry): “If the letter T is reflected along a vertical axis, it appears the same. This is sometimes called vertical symmetry.” I said that one should put “a mirror vertically”. If you think it is ambiguous, however, I will change “vertically symmetric” with “has a vertical symmetry axis” or “has a left-right symmetry”. Or I could add a picture.

Comment: The very next sentence in the Wikipedia article you quote says that this is an ambiguous phrasing and best avoided. I must say that I didn't know it was ambiguous: this is the first time I've seen anyone say that an object with a vertical axis of symmetry has vertical symmetry, and I have understood since I was a small child that an object with a vertical axis of symmetry has horizontal symmetry (and so, presumably, has the person who upvoted my comment). Since questions on PPCG should be unambiguous, I can only advise a rewrite which explicitly uses the word "axis" everywhere.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, ok, thank you very much for your comment, I will change the question. Do you think I should change also the title?

Comment: Yes, but in the title it would suffice to say "symmetric". Which symmetry is a detail which can be left for the body.

Comment: @geokavel, thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

## Implement a BrainFlump interpreter

[BrainFlump](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/brainflump) is the latest alternate memory model brainfuck-esque turing tarpit.

It operates on a memory model we call a "Dump", which is simply an un-ordered collection of integers, with a pointer indicating the current item to operate on. As it is "unordered", when moving to the next item, one is simply chosen at random (chosen uniformly between the items that are not the currently selected item) and the operation pointer is moved to that item.

### Commands

```
+   #Increment the item at the pointer
-   #Decrement the item at the pointer
:   #Add a 0 to the dump, and move the pointer to it
;   #Move the pointer to a random item that is not the pointer's current position
(   #Skip to the matching ) if the item at the pointer is 0
)   #Skip to the matching ( if the item at the pointer is not 0
,   #Read a single character from STDIN and push its ascii value to the dump
    #This also moves the pointer to the new item
.   #Print the current item at the pointer modulo 127 as an ASCII character
```

### Other notes

- When the `;` command is used if the dump contains only 1 item, a new `0` is pushed to the dump, and the pointer is moved to it
- The `.` command does not pop the item from the dump
- When the `,` command is used if STDIN has been exhausted, a new `0` is pushed to the dump, and the pointer is moved to it
- Any item in the dump who's value is `0` is not considered to exist, unless it is the item at the pointer, therefore to "pop" an item from the dump, you simply set its value to `0`
- Nested loops *are* supported
- The random number generator used for the interpreter does not have to be cryptographically secure, but must chose with uniformity.
- BrainFlump does not support floating point numbers or negative integers. Attempting to decrement a number below `0` has no effect.
- The maximum value of an item in the dump is `255`

### Examples/Testcases

#### brainf**k emulation

```
++++++(;++++++++;-);.
```

This should output `0`

#### Explanation

```
++++++        #Increment the first item to 6
(             #While the item under the pointer is not 0
    ;         #Move to another item in the dump
              #    Note the first time this loop runs,
              #    this will insert a new item
    ++++++++  #Increment the new item by 8
    ;         #Switch to another item in the dump
              #    Note there are only 2 items currently,
              #    So this will switch to the only other
              #    item, the one we initially incremented to 6
    -         #Decrement the item
)             #Repeat the loop if the item is not 0
;             #Switch to the other item
              #    Note this switches the pointer back to
              #    The item we have been incrementing by
              #    8 each loop
.             #Output as ASCII character
```

This is effectively a `6*8` operation, followed by an output, and is nearly identical to brainf**k's `++++++[>++++++++<-]>.` program, which also outputs `0`.

Note, however, that brainf**k-esque dump manipulation is only deterministically possible if there are never more than 2 items in the dump.

#### Random output

```
+:++:+++:++++:+++++:;.
```

This will actually always output an unprintable character, however which character is output will be random each time, selected from: `SOH, STX, EST, EOT, ENQ`, ie ASCII characters 1-5. In a correctly implemented interpreter, this output should be uniformly random between the 5 possibilities.

#### Explanation

```
+      #Increment first item to 1
:      #Add new item and move to it
++     #Increment new item to 2
:      #Add new item and move to it
+++    #Increment new item to 3
:      #Add new item and move to it
++++   #Increment new item to 4
:      #Add new item and move to it
+++++  #Increment new item to 5
:      #Add new item and move to it
       #    Note this last item is added because ; will
       #    always switch to an item that is *not* the
       #    currently selected item
;      #Switch randomly to an item in the dump
.      #Output as ASCII character
```

To give a little more info on this, by the time the `;` command is reached, the dump should look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0
          ^
```

As `;` *always* switches to a different item, the result will be the pointer at one of the non-zero items.

#### cat

```
,(.,)
```

Nice and simple, and identical to brainf**k's cat program.

For scoring purposes, you should use [this](https://gist.github.com/gunnerwolf/394c35161fbba6db85671c9b7ba80479) gist as input when testing.

#### When will it end?

```
++++(,:+++++;++(;++++++;--):++++;---)
```

This program doesn't output anything, but runs for a non-deterministic amount of time.

#### Explanation

```
++++             #Increment first item to 4
(                #Start loop
    ,            #Read char from STDIN to new item in dump
    :+++++       #Push 5 to dump
    ;++          #Switch to random item in dump and add 2
    (            #Start loop
        ;++++++  #Switch to random item in dump and add 6
        ;--      #Switch to random item in dump and subtract 2
    )            #End loop
    :++++        #Push 4 to dump
    ;---         #Switch to random item in dump and subtract 3
)
```

This one is a little tricky, as `;` will never switch to a `0` (Remember items with a value of `0` are considered to not exist)

The inner loop will only exit if `;--` switches to a number `<= 2`

The outer loop will only exit if `;---` switches to a number `<= 3`

Due to the inherent randomness of the language, this *should* always terminate... eventually.

For scoring purposes, you should use the exact string `Hello, World!` as input when testing.

### Scoring

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) meaning the interpreter that on average runs the fastest, wins!

Scoring will be determined by running each of the 4 test-cases above 100 times, and determining an average runtime (due to the inherent randomness of the language, a high number of runs should be made to minimise anomalous results).

Then once you have an average for each testcase, sum the 4 times, and that is your final score. **Lower is better**

Comment: I feel like a lot of time will come from the RNG, so better solutions might sacrifice some  "randomness"  for speed  - You might want to standardise "randomness"

Answer (score 4):

### Zoom box drawing characters

Here are some sample box drawing characters:

```
  ╷
 ┌┴┐
╶┤ ├╴
 └┬┘
  ╵
```

How do we zoom them? Well, we need to triple their size. The result looks like this:

```
      ╻
      ┃
      ┃
   ┏━━┻━━┓
   ┃     ┃
   ┃     ┃
╺━━┫     ┣━━╸
   ┃     ┃
   ┃     ┃
   ┗━━┳━━┛
      ┃
      ┃
      ╹
```

As you can see, what happens is this:

- Each box drawing character is replaced by its heavy version (for extra thickness)
- The box drawing characters are extended using the heavy horizontal and heavy vertical characters, resulting in a separation of three between the original characters

You can use any reasonable character I/O format. You will only need to support spaces and the 15 basic box drawing characters, plus newlines if you need them as line separators. You can only require rectangular input, but your output may contain arbitrary whitespace padding, except on the left, so that the characters in the zoomed image are aligned.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes that violates no standard loopholes wins, but if you're using UTF-8 encoding then you can score all box drawing characters as 1 each.

Comment: RIP Charcoal, it doesn't use UTF-8 :P

Answer (score 4):

## Does it have a square? (simple version) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

Given a matrix of `0`s and `1`s, determine if there are 4 points that are `1` and are the corners of a square.

Here's an example to clarify, with a possible square (in bold):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Another possible square is the following:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

There are many squares in this matrix, but the point isn't to count the squares, just to determine if there's a square in it. Since there is a square in it, your solution, given this matrix, must return a truthy value.

Given this matrix, your solution must return a falsy value:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 0
```

You can see there's no square in there.

## Rules

- Since the input is a matrix, it will always be rectangular.
- Probably needless to say, the sides of a square must be equal.
- The corners of a square must all be `1`.
- A square must have at least side length 2 to be considered a square, otherwise this challenge would be extremely trivial.
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024), as usual, are forbidden.

## Test cases

*This section is under construction.*

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144923/73111).

Comment: Is a 2x2 square a square?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn *A square must have at least side length 2 to be considered a square*

Comment: Can one's solution require that the matrix' dimensions are given? If so, can the input be a single list instead of a nested one?

Comment: @Jonathan [Relevant](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/48198) but not necessarily answering your question.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Does your language really not support nested arrays (like e.g. Neim)? Otherwise I don't see why...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I was thinking of languages like C, where I find it simply nicer to only have to deal with one list, even though the language can handle nested lists. I just wanted to ask about, not necessarily influence, the validity of a solution taking a flat list.

Answer (score 4):

## LaTeX truth tables

Write a program or a function that accepts the list of outputs from a logic function and outputs the LaTeX code for its truth table.

The inputs should be labeled as lowercase letters `a-z`, and the output should be labelled as `F`. The length of list of inputs will always be shorter than `2^25`, which means that number of inputs will always be less than 25, so you can use letters from lowercase alphabet for input names.

### Input

A number `n` of inputs and list of length `2^n` of binary numbers which represents the outputs of a logical function.

### Output

LaTeX code that produces the truth table for that function. Input and output values should be centered in rows.
There must be a line between table header and its values and between inputs and output, so the code should be similar to that below.

```
\begin{tabular}{c * <NUMBER OF INPUTS>|c}
<INPUTS>&F\\
\hline
<INPUT VECTOR i>&<OUTPUT>\\
\end{tabular}
```

### Example

Input:

```
2
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Output:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c}
a & b & F \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Which when displayed in LaTeX shows the following truth table

[image: Truth table]

### General rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: What happens if there are >25 outputs? Do we label them `abcdef...uvwxz`? Also, just to be clear, can we assume that there will be at most 25 variables present? Also, what is the winning criterion? (I recommend [tag:code-golf] for this challenge).

Comment: There are not going to be > 25 input variables. I was thinking of shortest code so yeah, code-golf :)

Comment: Okay. For the >25 variables part you might want to specify it, and you should add a note saying what the winning criterion is, and you might also want to consider what tags to use (probably just code-golf and maybe math, really). Once you add that ping me and I'd be happy to check it over :)

Comment: "The inputs should be labeled as lowercase letters a-z, and the output should be labelled as y." It isn't really clear from this whether 'y' can also be part of the inputs or not (I guess not). Another thing that came to my mind is that you could give the possibility of taking 'n' as an input in addition to the list of '2^n' values, since that could remove some annoying boilerplate from some answers and this challenge seems more about generating a structured output than computing the base-2 logarithm of a number.

Comment: I agree, should I label the output name to something else? Like uppercase F or something like that? I'll add number of inputs as an input.

Answer (score 4):

## Formulize the sum: Faulhaber's formula

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Sums of the form `Σkⁿ` over `k in 1..x` can be turned into a polynomial of `x` whenever `n` is a natural number.

#### Examples

```
Σ1 = x
Σk = (1/2)x²+(1/2)x
Σk²= (1/3)x³+(1/2)x²+(1/6)x
```

#### Criteria

You will take `n` as a non-negative integer input and output the coefficients in reduced fraction form of the resulting polynomial from leading coefficient down to the last non-zero coefficient.

This is code-golf, shortest code wins.

#### Test cases

```
0 #=> 1
1 #=> 1/2 1/2
2 #=> 1/3 1/2 1/6
3 #=> 1/4 1/2 1/4  0
4 #=> 1/5 1/2 1/3  0 -1/30
5 #=> 1/6 1/2 5/12 0 -1/12
```

(extra spacing here is just for clarity and is not necessary.)

Comment: 0 is `positive`? `non-negative` is better.

Comment: Fixed @user202729

Comment: Is outputting floating point coefficient allowed? Is errors from floating point imprecision allowed?

Comment: @user202729 No, because you get some fractions like `5/12` or `1/3` with non-terminating decimal expansions.

Comment: What about the latter question? / Is errors from integer overflow (for large arguments) allowed?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, though you program should be able to handle up to, say, `n = 20`.

Comment: I think the answer for `3` should be `1/4 1/2 1/4`.

Comment: @alephalpha thanks

Comment: Don't we already have a Bernoulli numbers challenge?

Answer (score 4):

## A Fine-Grained Mesh

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

If you've used Matlab before, it's highly likely that you've heard of `meshgrid`.  It's a function that has since mostly been obsoleted by broadcasting, but it still has its uses sometimes.

The function itself is relatively simple.  Given two vectors `x` and `y` of length `m` and `n`, create two 2-dimensional matrices `X` and `Y` both with `m` columns and `n` rows such that:

1. Any row of `X` is a copy of `x`
2. Any column of `Y` is a copy of `y`

But typing out `meshgrid(x,y)` takes so long, you know? I'd like to be more efficient with my coding. Your job is to reimplement this function in  the fewest bytes possible.

Standard loopholes disallowed.

Comment: This is a classical case of [do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8079#8079) which is discouraged. The reason is that some languages might have something similar that is not quite equal, and then it is always the question: Where do you draw the line? I recommend against banning built ins.

Comment: @flawr I removed that as a requirement.

Comment: You could add "builtins that compute this are allowed but a second implementation without using that builtin are strongly encouraged"

Comment: what types are `x` and `y`? Int, float, char, ...?

Comment: `x` and `y` can be any vector-like type.  Lists, arrays, actual vectors...

Answer (score 4):

## Make a Sierpinski triangle

Your challenge is to output a n-th order right-angle Sierpinski triangle, similar to this (third-order):

```
#
# #
#   #
# # # #
#       #
# #     # #
#   #   #   #
# # # # # # # #
```

#### Input:

A number, n, and a character (in this example '#');

#### Output:

A 2**n (two to the n) line Sierpinski triangle, made of the given character.
You could consider it a two-state cellular automaton: the cells are separated by a single spaaace; if it is on, it contains the given character; Otherwise is contains a spaaace.

#### Examples:

in:

```
0 *
```

out:

```
*
```

explanation:

2**0=1

in:

```
1 *
```

out:

```
*
* *
```

in:

```
2 *
```

out:

```
*
* *
*   *
* * * *
```

### Winner:

this is codegolf so the winner is the answer with the least bytes. (*NOTE*: might add something tho do with triangles of the same character.)

#### Hint:

it might be helpful to know that the n-th line contains the previous line xor that line shifted right by one cell (x^(x>>1)).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thanks for using the sandbox! There is [a challenge to draw an Sierpinski Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/draw-a-sierpinski-triangle) which is broad enough to allow your format, so the challenge might be considered a duplicate. Then again I think the old challenge is no longer up to the current site standards and should probably be closed ...

Comment: This is also close enough to [Generate Pascal's triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3815/194) that by the standards of this site (can answers be copied with trivial modifications?) I would consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

## -(-(--x)--))> Code Kebabs! <-(-(--x)--))

---

Your goal is to parse Code Kebabs, they look like this:

```
-x--> 8
2 <-(-(--x)--))
-x-x-x--> -10
--x> 255
```

A Code Kebab is made up of 3 parts, the stick, the tip (< and >), and the stand (the number compared by)

```
stick tip stand 
--x-- >   -5
```

#### The stick

---

The stick contains 4 operators, and the variable (x)
The operators are listed here, in order of precedence:

1. ( ... ) | Brackets. They are the "veggies" on a code kebab. Everything inside them runs before the rest of the kebab, with the last, deepest pair going first. Brackets can be nested.
2. v-- | Suffix decrementation. This is one of the 4 parts of the stick, and decrements the value supplied to it by one.
3. v-v | Subtraction. This is the 2nd part of the stick, and subtracts the two values.
4. --x | Prefix decrementation. This is the 3rd part of the stick, and decrements the value supplied to it by one.
5. -v | Negation. This is the 4th and final part of the stick, and inverts the value supplied.

Each operator returns it's result, and can be used as input for other operators.

#### The Tip

---

The tip is one of two symbols: < or >
When the tip is <, the stand must be left of it, with the tip being left of the stick.
When it is >, the stand is to it's right, with the tip being on the right of the stick.

#### The Stand

---

The stand is any integer. That's all there really is to say about it.

#### Execution of the kebab

---

You can't execute a kebab without eating it!

Kebabs are executed in a loop until their condition (The result of the stick being less than the stand's value) is fulfilled. When execution is finished, the variable (x) is set to the result of the stick, X is printed, and execution resumes again unless the condition is fulfilled.

When execution starts for the first time, X is set to `10` beforehand.

#### TODO

---

- Add test cases.
- Clear a few things up.
- Make the description of execution a bit clearer?

Comment: You should describe the difference between pre and post decrement.

Comment: Also, how are the input variables initialized?

Comment: A test case that has something like `-x--5` to force parsing it as a subtraction and unary negation, rather than post-decrement `x`, would be very good.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Numbers aren't mentioned as a requirement for parsing, so -x--x would probably work better. But yea, good idea.

Comment: @Pavel The input *variable* X is set to `10` beforehand, as mentioned in `The execution of the kebab`

Comment: Is this correct? And if not, where is my flaw? The input is the Code Kebab (i.e. `-x--> 8`) with `x=10` by default, and the output is the `x` once it fulfills the Kebab check. So for `-x--> 8` with `x=10` as start, it will do `x--` first (so it becomes `x=9`), and then the `-x` negation (so it becomes `x=-9`), and then checks it with the tip (`-9 > 8`). This is false, so it continues with `x` now being `-9`? So then `x--` again (`x=-10`), then `-x` again (`x=10`), and then the check again (`10 > 8`). Which is true, so it outputs `10` as result? I have the feeling I misunderstand it a bit..

Comment: Also, why is suffix decrementation before prefix? In most languages (Java, JS, C, etc.) it's usually the other way around.

Comment: And one more question, is something like `---x` (negation & prefix decrementation), or `x---x` (suffix decrementation & subtraction) a possible valid input? Or would these always be surrounded by parenthesis (`---x` would be `-(--x)` instead; `x---x` would be `(x--)-x` or `x-(--x)` instead).

Answer (score 4):

## Extremely small data compressor

In 2014 Jarek Duda at Purdue University wrote a paper containing several ideas for encoding computer data, entitled **“Asymmetric numeral systems: entropy coding combining speed of Huffman coding with compression rate of arithmetic coding"**. The paper  is available at Cornell University Library’s ArXiv project: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2540

One of the many fascinating things about this paper is that it begins by describing an extremely simple data compression algorithm, using the concept of the "Uniform asymmetric binary systems (uABS)". In fact, it is so simple, that you can implement it in only a few lines of code.

Basically it attempts to interpret a sequence of input symbols as a single Integer, and as each symbol comes in the Integer can be appended with new information. The trick is that the Integer is represented not using a place-value binary number system, but an alternative system. This representation is designed so that sequences of symbols which occur with higher probability will be represented by a smaller amount of space within the Integer's encoding.

### Challenge

You will implement the simple uABS compression algorithm, so that given a sequence of 0s and 1s, your program will compress them into a (usually) smaller sequence of 0s and 1s.

### Pseudocode

The algorithm in psuedocode is as follows:

- Begin with an Integer X, and set it to 1. This will be the main Integer that we append during the algorithm.
- The input data is a sequence of symbols, each 0 or 1, called Input
- Find the probability P that any given symbol in Input is 1, (the number of 1s divided by the total number of symbols)
- For each symbol S in Input, set X to the output of the function Encode(x,s,p)
- After processing all the input symbols, output the final integer X.
  -- This encoded integer will hopefully have less bits than the input

The Encode function itself can be described as follows:

$$
Encode(x,s,p)=
\left\{
    \begin{array}{11}
         \mbox{if } s = 0 & \big\lceil\frac{x+1}{1-p}\big\rceil-1 \\
         \mbox{if } s = 1 & \big\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\big\rfloor 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Where

$$
\begin{array}{11}
   s \text{ is a symbol, either 0 or 1} \\ 
   x \text{ is the Integer} \\
   p \text{ is the probability that any symbol in the Input data is 1 } \\
   \lceil \rceil \text{ is the mathematical ceiling function  } \\
  \lfloor \rfloor \text{ is the mathematical floor function }
\end{array}
$$

### Notes

- The input is a sequence of symbols, each symbol being 0 or 1, in any method that is available in your chosen language. Examples include a sequence of ascii characters '0' '1', an array of integers, etc.
- The output will be a sequence of symbols in the same format as the input sequence. The output sequence represents the compressed version of the input data.
- Empty input data has undefined behavior.
- Input data containing only 0s has undefined behavior.
- Sometimes the encoded Integer might have more bits than the input, not less. This typically happens when the number of 1s and 0s is relatively even. Data with an unbalanced number of 0s and 1s results in better compression.
- You may assume that the size of Integer will be your language's largest integer type. The test cases outside this range can be ignored for your language.
- Note that if you are trying to test this by 'decoding' or 'decompressing' the compressed data, and compare it to the original, one would have to store additional information, such as the length of input and probability P, but for simplicity this has been left out of the challenge.

### Example Input and Output

Short examples:

```
Input             Output    
10                101
10010100000       1011101001
1111              1
11111111111       1
10000000          11011
10011111010101    10110000100101
```

Longer examples:

```
Input  11111110110111110111111111011111
Output 11111000011110110

Input  000000000001000000010000000000001100000000001
Output 1110000101100111000011111

Input  000000000001000000010000000000001100000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
Output 1010100110111110010111011110110101010
```

### Scoring

- The program with the fewest number of characters wins.

Comment: 1. IMO the pseudocode could be made clearer by firstly explaining what "machine integer" means (does it mean "unbounded integer" aka "big integer"?) and secondly golfing it a bit: using a "foreach" loop notation for `S` and eliminating the variable `X'`. 2. I think it would be helpful to be explicit about how `p` should be derived from the input. I presume that it means looping over the input twice, once to count and once to compress. 3. IMO restricting the input format to strings of ASCII `0` and `1` detracts from the core challenge. Why not allow arrays/lists of integers?

Comment: Thanks, i have revised.

Comment: I really like this one. Something quasi-practical, and yet simple and small enough to be fun. Just to be clear, the output is the binary representation fo the integer X, without any leading zeros, correct?

Comment: Also, you mention "input size of at least 128 symbols", but it might be more important to specify output size limit, since many languages have hard bounds on maximum integer size. Since output size varies for the same input length, it might have to be something like "you may assume that the number of symbols in the output is less than or equal to the number of bits in your language's largest integer type". (The last test case would then be optional in languages that can handle only up to 32 bit integers).

Comment: yes the output is the binary representation of the final integer X, i believe the leading zeros is correct.  do you think 32 bit is the good limit or 64, since modern machines tend to be 64 bit? thanks

Comment: 32 is probably a reasonable limit, one that most languages can handle without need for external libraries.

Comment: @sunar thanks, i have updated.

Comment: I assume the intent is for `P` to be calculated as `# of '1' in the input / # of symbols in the input`? That seems like it would match the definition given, but it would be helpful if it's described explicitly.

Comment: Done, thanks....

Answer (score 4):

## Classical construction golf: Wernick's list No. 47 [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

### Background

[**Compass-and-straightedge construction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction), a.k.a. classical construction, is the construction of lengths, angles, and other geometric figures using only an idealized ruler and compass. A **ruler** can only be used to draw a straight line passing through two given points; a **compass** can only be used to draw a circle with two given points (a center, and a point on the circle).

All compass and straightedge constructions consist of repeated application of five basic constructions using the points, lines and circles that have already been constructed. These are:

- Creating the line through two existing points
- Creating the circle through one point, with another point as the center
- Creating the point which is the intersection of two existing, non-parallel lines
- Creating the one or two points in the intersection of a line and a circle (if they intersect)
- Creating the one or two points in the intersection of two circles (if they intersect).

[image: Five basic constructions]

In addition to these listed on Wikipedia, we have the sixth basic construction:

- Creating an arbitrary point on the plane, possibly with a constraint:

  - On a line ("line" includes straight lines and circles)
  - Not on a line
  - On a closed or open part of a line, bounded by existing points on it
  - Inside a closed or open region, bounded by existing lines

In any geometric problem, we have an initial set of symbols (points and lines), an algorithm, and some results. From this perspective, geometry is equivalent to an axiomatic algebra, replacing its elements by symbols.

This is the basis of the new kind of [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf): **classical construction golf**.

### Challenge

[**Wernick's list**](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2016volume16/FG201610.pdf) is a collection of construction problems. The common objective is to recover the three vertices of a triangle, given three of its 16 *characteristic points*. They include:

- \$A, B, C, O\$: three vertices and circumcenter,
- \$M_a, M_b, M_c, G\$: the side midpoints and centroid,
- \$H_a, H_b, H_c, H\$: three feet of altitudes and orthocenter,
- \$T_a, T_b, T_c, I\$: three feet of internal angle bisectors and incenter.

Out of the 139 problems, some are solvable by construction, but some are not. The problem we'll tackle here is problem 47, where the given points are:

- \$A\$: a vertex.
- \$H_a\$: the foot of the altitude on side \$a\$; that is, the opposite side of the vertex \$A\$.
- \$T_b\$: the foot of the bisector of angle \$B\$.

Given these three points, recover the other vertices \$B\$ and \$C\$.

[image]

### Scoring & Winning criterion

Every usage of the **six basic constructions** (shown above) counts. For the line intersections, **creating each point adds 1 score**, e.g. if you need both intersections of two circles, you get 2 score from the step.

The solution with the lowest score wins.

#### Scoring example

**Task**: Construct the midpoint of two points \$A\$ and \$B\$.

**Solution**:

- Draw circle \$C_1\$ with center \$A\$ going through \$B\$. (+1)
- Draw circle \$C_2\$ with center \$B\$ going through \$A\$. (+1)
- Draw two intersections \$X, Y\$ of two circles \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$. (+2)
- Draw line \$f\$ going through the two intersections. (+1)
- Draw line \$g\$ going through the two given points. (+1)
- Draw the intersection \$M\$ of \$f\$ and \$g\$. (+1)

The score of this construction is 7.

[image: Example task]

### Tools

**[GeoGebra](https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/geogebra/geogebra.html)** is a free online geometry tool. In addition to basic and advanced constructions, it has **construction protocol** feature which clearly shows the steps used to create the final image. For the above example task, the construction protocol looks like this:

[image: Example construction protocol]

Out of 9 steps in total, the points \$A\$ and \$B\$ are given, so we can confirm that seven steps are taken for this particular construction.

It also supports **[scripting](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Scripting)** (in GGBScript and JS) for those who want to view this challenge as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf). Among many geometry commands, the **[Prove](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Prove_Command)** and **[ProveDetails](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/ProveDetails_Command)** commands may help you identify if a particular construction is indeed correct.

### Notes

I'm using a relatively easy problem here, in order to see how this new challenge type is received. If it goes well, I'll propose some harder and open-ended problems later.

---

### Meta

- <s>Is this actually on-topic on PPCG? I'm asking this since this is the first challenge of its kind.</s> I'll assume on-topic unless someone says otherwise on [this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16688/78410).
- <s>Maybe we need to tweak the difficulty of the challenge at hand. Is it too easy or too hard? Any other suggestions? I picked Wernick's list because it's not something you may see on Euclidea or similar, and the optimal (or elegant) solutions for many of the problems are not yet known.</s> I'll go for the task this time, and try to ramp up in subsequent challenges.

Comment: I think it would be a stretch to consider this on-topic: proofs in logic can be argued to be as good as programs by reference to the Curry-Howard correspondence, but I don't really see extending that to proofs in general. It might be more interesting to instead ask for a program which generates proofs and score by the length of the generated proofs (although since the linked paper talks about a 6000-line program to search for them, that may be outside the scope of a reasonable PPCG challenge).

Comment: On the difficulty of the given theorem: without much effort (5 minutes maximum) I have a solution scoring 16. It's certainly much easier than the existing [tag:proof-golf] questions to get *an* answer, although I can believe that there may still be room to golf my solution.

Comment: (In fact I've spotted one unnecessary intersection, so 15).

Comment: Do you think this would be better here or on Puzzling?

Answer (score 4):

## Nearest neighbors in a square lattice

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [square-lattice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/square-lattice)

### Premise

Consider an infinite 2D square lattice. We can choose one point as the origin and label each point with a pair of integers that corresponds to points on the Euclidean plane:

[image]

Now consider the point at the origin, \$(0,0)\$. The set of lattice points closes to the origin (but not including the origin) is \$\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}\$. We will call this set the \$1\$st nearest neighbors. The set of lattice points closest to the origin but not including the \$1\$st nearest neighbors is \$\{(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)\}\$. We call this set the \$2\$nd nearest neighbors

Now we can define the \$k\$-th nearest neighbors as the set of points closest to the origin and not included in the union of the set of \$n\$-th nearest neighbors for \$n\in\{1,2,...k-1\}\$.

Define the sequence \$NN(k)\$ as the length of the set of \$k\$-th nearest neighbors.

### Task

Given \$k\$, compute \$NN(k)\$. This is [A105352](https://oeis.org/A105352) on OEIS without the first element.

### Rules

- You may use 0- or 1- based indexing.
- Given \$k\$, you may either output the first \$k\$ elements of the sequence or the \$k\$-th element.
- You may alternatively take no input and output the sequence indefinitely.
- Standard loopholes disallowed.

Here are some 1-indexed test cases:

```
n   NN(k)
1   4
8   8
9   4
10  8
38  16
52  8
80  8
121 24
145 12
```

Comment: [OEIS A105352](https://oeis.org/A105352).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks

Comment: Could you allow the infinite sequence \$\{NN(1),NN(2),NN(3),\ldots\}\$ as output (with no input)?

Comment: @Delfad0r Sure.

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64812/count-sums-of-two-squares). Just filter out zeroes.

Comment: @user202729 Do you think it's a dupe?

Comment: @dylnan I don't know...

Comment: IMO it's a dupe: adding a loop and an if test is a pretty trivial modification.

Answer (score 4):

### Breaking into 3 Palindromes:

As discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKhacWQ2fCs) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06208v2.pdf), every positive integer can be written as the sum of 3 palindrome integers.  Given a number "n", output these integers.

### Challenge

- This is a code golf challenge.  The shortest functional solution wins.
- The input number "n" will be any integer greater than 0 but less than 1,000,000,000.
- The three output numbers must be palindromes.  Their sum must be "n".
- A palindrome number is a number which is the same forwards as backwards.  It can have any number of digits.
- To make this easier, I will allow positive or negative palindrome integers.
- Output and input can be formatted in any what that is convenient as long as it can be readily understood.

### Examples

```
input: 5
output: 0,0,5

input: 1234
output: 1001,222,11

input: 3141592
output: 2200022,926629,14941
```

Comment: This is actually a very interesting problem.  The paper which proved that this would work for any base lists 40 different algorithms that are used to find these values depending on the value of "n".  I suppose there should be a requirement to solve this in a reasonable about of time to avoid brute force but I don't know how I should phrase that.

Comment: It's up to you, but time limit requires a particular computer to test the solutions on.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to link that paper in the challenge. Also, I tried to bruteforce in 05AB1E, and the `1234` case already times out after 60 sec, so I won't even have to try `3141592`.. It barely doesn't make it within the 60 sec, [but does output most of the possible outputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxTkw43BdYaH17s4u8ZeLj//39DI2MTAA). Maybe make this a _[fastest-code]_ challenge instead of code-golf, so the goal is to solve it as fast as possible. Alternatively _[fastest-algorithm]_ could be used as well, but usually when someone find one, others will copy it.

Comment: Honestly, i don't think i am comfortable managing a fastest-algorithm challenge due to my own limited skill.  I'm a pretty amateur programmer so if someone uses languages, libraries, etc. I'm unfamiliar with I won't be able to fairly judge them.  This idea though (complicated but sounds simple) seems great for one of these challenges.

Comment: Would it be feasible to require the code to run within 20 minutes on Ideone?  Is that linked to my computer's abilities?

Comment: I think if you keep this at base 10 (decimal only) it's not so bad.

Comment: @ouflak I had no intention of leaving base 10.  I'm really liking the Ideone idea but am not sure if people would be ok with that.

Comment: http://www.rnta.eu/cgi-bin/three_palindromes/pal3.py and http://somethingorotherwhatever.com/sum-of-3-palindromes/
The speeds for these are bad at all. One in python the other in Javascript. I'm doing a C++ version (completely ungolfed) as I'm at a bit of a lull at the moment. It's just a translation of the Javascript code with some tweaks. I'll post a link to that as well. I would forget the timings and go with the straight up challenge.

Comment: I've done this up in non-golfed C++. Anybody know a site where I can put this online where people can run it? It's big, but fast.

Comment: The non-golfed C++ is 36 kbytes. Maybe limiting this to just the 4 digit case might be OK. I might try that in LUA and see what it looks like. This is such a great idea. Unfortunate that the algorithms are so lengthy.

Comment: @ouflak,  the fact that the algorithms are lengthy is why I thought this would make a good challenge.  It is ripe for optimization.  I'm worried about posting this challenge though as I'm sure there are many algorithms that will give an answer eventually but are so slow they defeat the purpose of the challenge.

Comment: Ok, I've sorted out a much shorter algorithm in LUA for the three digit case, un-golfed. https://repl.it/repls/AchingEnchantedHack. This has given me an idea for how to sort out the general case, which I think now actually might not be so bad.

Comment: Here is a solution that should work for any sized number. This is brutally un-golfed LUA. I haven't even taken the opportunity to use a recursive function where it obviously would apply. For 5 digit numbers and smaller, it's pretty quick, easily less than a second. For 6 digit numbers and above, it depends on how soon it finds the first set of palindromes. I had one number (390081) take a good five minutes on the test site. I'm sure it would be quicker on my machine. I'd like to think there are places for optimization for speed (as well as golfing). https://repl.it/repls/BlondWaryShareware

Comment: Just one other comment on your constraints, I wouldn't allow negative palindromes as I'm not convinced this makes it 'easier'. Should I start golfing this thing? ;)

Comment: @ouflak you can probably wait until i post it as a real question but your enthusiasm definitely implies I need to.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be a good idea to break this into two competitions: 1 for shortest code and limited to five digits. One for speed with no digit limit.

Comment: I would like to post this as a challenge for the Advent Golf Challenge - 2022.

Answer (score 4):

## The max() is not enough

[The max() is not enough](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173458/23513)

Comment: This could do with a better title, any suggestions?

Comment: "Max is only half the story"

Comment: *What if the largest integer in the list is not unique, do we output the second largest? I.e., with the list `[1,8,4,8]` do we output nothing because the `8` is duplicated, or do we output `4` instead being the largest unique integer?* EDIT: Scratch the italic part before. Also, I assume we can take the input in any reasonable format? As an integer list, integer-array, integer-stream, comma-separated string, newline- or space-delimited STDIN, etc? Or is it mandatory to input it in a comma-separated string format?

Comment: Ignore the first question. Just noticed it's either nothing if all values in the list are unique, or the max otherwise (even if the largest is not unique). In that case: Can the list contain negative integers or zero? And are we allowed to output another falsey value instead of an empty output?

Comment: Can we have more test cases with all elements equal

Comment: I have a 5-byter ready, it's a great challenge if it isn't a duplicate!

Comment: @Quintec Great suggestion to focus on "max" - definitely inspired the new title!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen / Anyone: I think failing to follow the rules to the letter should be permissible BUT carry some level of bytes as a penalty. I'm not sure what the usual is here - how about 15 bytes each for either using some other input format _and_ for outputting garbage instead of no output?

Comment: @JoKing Of course, although I'm curious to know - is this somehow non-trivial to infer from the existing cases? What's the catch? :P

Comment: @maxb This will like be up "for real" sometime tomorrow UK time. Good luck!

Comment: Nah, but it would help people catch if their solutions are invalid. Also, I would discourage byte bonuses/penalties, and just let solutions take input how they like rather than overriding the site defaults

Comment: @ElectricWarr The default is usually to have a flexible input and output formats. But if you insist on having a string comma-separated input, then I will use a split by comma instead to make it into a list in my program itself instead of taking the 15 bytes penalty, considering my full program with list input is just 5 bytes, and changing the comma-separated string to a list is +4 bytes (way below 15 ;p). I would advice to don't use penalties or bonusses at all for challenges btw (and use flexible I/O, but the I/O choice is still up to you of course if you insist on comma-separated strings).

Comment: Btw, about "_Assume input integers may be more than one digit but no larger than 4 bytes_", your last test case has 6-byte numbers?

Comment: And your third test case should result in `1` instead of `9`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I figure I'll try strict requirements this time around and if it's a problem I'll avoid them in future.

On 6-byte numbers - ha! - good point, I'll reword that. Of course I should have foreseen that _here_ of all places "bytes" is a measure of length first and as a quantity of information second!

Comment: Seems ready to go now but I'll hold until tomorrow just in case there's more feedback to come.

Fixed the copy/paste test case.

Comment: @ElectricWarr Sounds good by me. +1 for the challenge in general and how it looks right now (and thanks for using the Sandbox btw, loads of new users don't do this! :D). I've prepared my 9-bytes answer, so when it goes live I'll post it when I can (unless someone else beat me to it in the same language of course).

Comment: `Polyglot, 30 bytes` Takes +15 for not taking any input and +15 for not outputting anything

Comment: "we don't didn't"?

Comment: May the input be empty?

Comment: [Adding bonus is not a good idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/69850).

Comment: I would strongly recommend removing *+15 points for each rule violation.*

Comment: Ok, I see your point @JoKing & DJ

Comment: @user202729 Thank you! Updated/ing.

Comment: Posted! Thank you and good luck! <3

Answer (score 4):

[Posted to main.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199658/game-of-game-of-life)

Comment: The initial set of squares should have a guaranteed distance from each other set of squares.  `grid` needs better specification.  What does "nearby square" mean?  Other than that, solid spec.

Comment: 1) The wording is weird on the Game of Life rule explanation. Please take a look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules) and clarify them. Currently, I'm not sure if a cell can change color if it's surrounded by more opponents than allies. Also, it seems to be implied that a live cell surrounded by 3 neighbors dies (which I'm pretty sure wasn't your intention). 2) What happens when no colors remain on the board? 3) Nitpick: the "this" in "it has at this time" threw me off - "that" instead, perhaps?

Comment: 4a) Since there's no explicit ban on cooperation, it's allowed by default. Was this your intention? 4b) Can bots communicate with each other? 5) Can bots store data across games? 6) Can we get a more easy-to-use system of storing data within one game? Scopes are useful for this: `function externalFunc() { /* Storage */ return function gameLoopFunc(args) { /* Code */ }; }` 7) `next` is not very robust. Some people (including myself) will remake the game simulation to gain access to more advanced functionality. 8) What happens if the returned value isn't within 2 cells of one of my own cells?

Comment: 9a) Why is selecting a live cell that is not your own a legal move, despite not doing anything? 9b) Is it legal to pass a move *always*? If so, what should we return if we want to pass a turn? 9b2) If it's not legal to pass a turn... why? It sounds pretty useful and makes sense. Please consider it.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thanks, I've clarified that now.

Comment: @Alion I've fixed 1, 3.  I've removed `next` - good point (7).  I've changed access to `localStorage` to access to `this`, clears between games (5,6). I've changed the scoring to a percentage and clarified draws (2).  I've clarified that passing values out of bounds is illegal (8) and what (9a) does. I've also made passing legal (9b/c).

(4) I did intend for cooperation (but not communication) to be legal; I've clarified that.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Splendid work. That being said, I'm not done yet. 10) Typos: id > it (line 2 of rule explanation), bot's > bots' (last restriction). 11) Can bots modify the grid passed to them (in the non-malicious sense)? 12) Black doesn't immediately strike me as a living cell. I'd recommend specifying that there exist neutral living cells (I only realized this during my 4th reading). 13) What format should submissions be? Template and example submissions both work. 14) Controller: If you haven't already, you should check out [Dave's JS KotH framework](https://github.com/davidje13/koth-webplayer).

Comment: 15) You've opened Pandora's Box with cooperation restriction. I'll illustrate what I mean with several abstract examples. GrudgeBot and PassiveBot: GrudgeBot will not attack PassiveBot, because PassiveBot doesn't bother GrudgeBot. FriendlyBot: Attempts to make friends with bots that it comes into contact with by testing if they will attack it. 2 instances would quickly team up after meeting each other. AlgoBot: Runs simulations and tests how well other bots play according to its idea of "optimal". 2 instances quickly realize that the other is playing optimal or near-optimal moves and team up.

Comment: 15 cont.) So, where do you draw the line? 16) `performance.now()` for timing purposes. Introduces unpredictability, but lets bots police their own time instead of their creators having to wildly guess the right values. Allowed or not? 17) [tag:cellular-automata], [tag:game], [tag:grid] (maybe).

Comment: Whew, what a rampage. Despite all of that, I'm impatiently looking forward to this hitting main. Expect to see me there immediately. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you very much!  I've fixed (10)-(12).  I'll add an example submission when I'm finished the controller - and I will definitely check out that framework!
(15) - Good point, but I don't want to give an advantage to people who build multiple bots.  I've added a clarification that a test for "too much cooperation" is preset move sequences and the like - identifying a bot by its strategy is okay.  There's room for interpretation, but I trust that non-malicious entries will be reasonable.  All of your examples I'm okay with. :)  I will add some tags.

Comment: @Alion I know it's taken way too long for me to get around to this, but if you're still interested...

Answer (score 4):

## The Hungry Moose

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176251/the-hungry-mouse#comment424408_176251).

Moose face harsh conditions during the winter. According to one [source](https://www.denali.org/denalis-natural-history/moose-in-winter/):

> Their winter foods are lower quality than what they eat in summer and provides less energy, consequently, they need to eat more of it. During harsh winters, having both extreme cold temperatures and deep snow, moose expend more energy than they take in and many can starve.

### Challenge

At noon on day 1, a hungry moose starts at a food source (the top left corner). Each morning, the moose may either walk to any 8-adjacent square or stay in place. Each evening, the moose clears the food and snow from its location (adding its net nutritional value to its calorie store and setting that value in the array to 0), and before the end of the day loses 1 calorie to the extreme cold.

The moose dies when its calorie store falls to 0 or below at the end of a day. In particular, if the value at the upper-left corner is 1, 0, or negative, the moose dies on day 1.

#### Input

A 2D array of integers. Negative numbers represent calorie-negative deep snow.

#### Output

The maximum number of days the moose can survive (counting day 1 as a full day).

#### Test cases (add)

```
6 0 -2 3
0 0 -5 -5
0 0 -1 3
8

42 -100 1
-100 -100 2
3 4 5
42

5 -3 1
1 -9 9
12
```

Comment: What happens if all the array values are all negative? Does the moose survive a single day or none at all?

Comment: A worked example would be useful. You also need to clarify if we can wrap around the array.

Answer (score 4):

### Inscriptio Labyrinthica

In the burial place of King Silo of Asturias there is an inscription that reads **SILO PRINCEPS FECIT** (*King Silo made this*).

[image: SILO PRINCEPS FECIT]

The first letter is found in the very middle, and from there one reads by going in any non-diagonal direction radiating outward.  The final letter is found on all four corners.  In this challenge, you'll generalize the process to make them.

### Input

A string ([or equivalent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/2216)), and an integer.  You may make the following assumptions about the input:

- The string will have an odd length.
- The integer will be an odd number between 1 and one less than twice the length of the string.

### Output

An *inscriptio labyrinthica* for the string, using the integer for the height (see models).  Output should be each letter with no spaces, line break as default to your system/language.

### Test cases

Note that an input of 1 or (length * 2 - 1) will result in a horizontal or vertical palindrome.

```
 Input: FOO, 3    Input: BAR, 1    Input: BAR, 3    Input: BAR, 5

Output: OOO      Output: RABAR    Output: RAR       Output: R
        OFO                               ABA               A
        OOO                               RAR               B
                                                            A
                                                            R

 Input: ABCDE, 5   Input: ABCDE, 3   Input: *<>v^, 3

Output: EDCDE     Output: EDCBCDE           ^v>v^
        DCBCD             DCBABCD           v><>v
        CBABC             EDCBCDE           ><*<>
        DCBCD                               v><>v
        EDCDE                               ^v>v^
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins.  [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) forbidden.

(I feel like I've seen one similar, but searching around I couldn't find it, and I happened to be reading about this king when I got the idea).

### Questions

In my original proposal, I had listed as a bonus to draw reading lines, but feedback was bonuses in code golf are discouraged.  I still like that idea and am thinking about integrating it as a a main part of the challenge, but don't know if that would over complicate it or actually make it more interesting.  The output for REI, 3 in such a case would be

```
I←E→I
↑ ↑ ↑
E←R→E
↓ ↓ ↓
I←E→I
```

The idea is that it would prevent simple flipping of data after calculating a quarter or half of the but still perhaps allow for some creative ways (I can think of some creative ways to do it shortly in some languages, but maybe it'll be overly complicated for others).

Comment: @trichoplax I've updated the challenge based on your feedback, let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks good to me. +1

Comment: you should now edit this to a link to the post and delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Babel on and on (working title...)

### Background

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a cornerstone of modern web development. It takes Javascript using new or proposed ECMAscript features and "transpiles" it into an older language version, so that browsers can run it without updates. In order to do this it inserts its own shim methods, and own custom transforms.

### The Challenge

**Your objective is to write the Javascript code which produces the largest babel output in characters. Your code must be less than or equal to 128 bytes in length**

Babel has an online, interactive compiler which you can access [HERE](https://babeljs.io/repl). It's highly recommended that you use this to form your answer. If you work locally, **you are restricted to modifying only the settings that the babel website allows you to modify.**. There is a guide on installing babel at the end of the question.

### Rules

- For consistency, you may use a Babel version between `7`, but not above `8.*` (when it eventually comes).
- You **may** change the interactive REPL's settings, source type, presets, options, and env-presets. You may change these settings locally if you are using a local installation of babel.
- You may only provide one input file.
- You **may not** exceed 128 bytes in your input file.
- You **may not** add your own plugins.
- You **may not** use the loophole listed below, or any of the standard loopholes.
- You **may not** use error output as a result. babel must transpile the code successfully under one of the allowed configurations.
- Neither your input or output need to run, or halt. The compilation just needs to output something.

## Examples

**41 in, [1075](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=usage&spec=true&loose=true&code_lz=N4FwXABA2gdHAUAzArgOwMYgJYHtUCp4BKYAGwFMRoBDAGgCMBdAXigEZaAmRgXyN6A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=Electron-1.8%252CNode-8.9&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=) out**

```
{t: [...(function*(){let [a,b]=[1,2]})]}
```

**32 in, [1101](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=usage&spec=true&loose=true&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CMDeATAXgDMBXAOwRgEsIyAqACgEocBfVoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=Electron-1.8%252CNode-8.9&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=) out**

```
export class b{d=function*(){}}
```

**125 in, [7336](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=usage&spec=true&loose=true&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBARjAvDAZgVzMKBLcAqACgEoBvAJwFMo0yxUMtcxDTLrb7Md9jyqa66LkxZ92ght2a82Azox6kAvitUBuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Ces2015-loose%2Ctypescript%2Cenv&prettier=true&targets=Electron-1.8%252CNode-8.9&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=) out**

```
const b = function*(){return function*(){return function*(){return function*(){return function*(){return function*(){}}}}}};
```

## Scoring

You must provide both the code and the settings you are using. For users of the online REPL, a link with the settings set in the URL suffices. The answer with the largest output with an input less than or equal to **128 bytes** wins. Unlike many challenges of this nature, settings do not cost any bytes of input.

## Setting up a local environment (OPTIONAL)

Most of the people doing this challenge will probably use babel's online transpiler to complete it. In the event that the website is taken down in the future or made inadequate for the challenge, it can be completed locally. Make a folder for the challenge, and in a shell in that folder, try something like the following:

**Install Babel (globally - you could do it locally)**
`sudo npm install -g @babel/core @babel/cli`
**Set your .babelrc with a preset (in this case env)**
`echo '{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}' > .babelrc`
**Install babel's dependencies**
`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/core`

Then, given an input file `test.js`, you can figure out your output score with

`babel test.js | wc -c`

## Happy Hunting!

## Questions

This is my first time ever posting one of these. Does everything look on the up-and-up?

Also, should this incorporate "the less characters of input, the better?". I kept trying to think of ways to reward a large output for a small input, but every way I considered changed the tone of the challenge significantly.

Also also, I know that codegolf users don't like being constrained to one language. Is this bound to be an exception or will that stop the question in its tracks?

**Proposed Tags**: `[BUSY BEAVER]`, `[Javascript]`, `[CODE CHALLENGE]`

Comment: Hi and thanks for using the sandbox! I'll start right off by saying I don't know enough about babel to particularly talk about if this will be interesting. I think this kind of challenge is fine, just like regex-golf. This should probably be tagged [tag:code-challenge] and shouldn't be tagged [tag:compiler]. I am concerned that you tie everything to an external site. While I doubt the site will go down, what happens when they update babel? Will it break the challenge? Since this is a bit abnormal, you may want to ask on meta (specifically about the online scoring) or in chat for more feedback.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks for the tags and pointing me to meta for this, I think I'll wind up clarifying things over there. And also, about the foreign site - it's not required, but makes it far, far easier. That's why I edited in the clause about being able to do it locally.

If the site is used, the settings are query parameters in the URL (but could be interpreted even if it went down). And contestants can do it locally, provided they post the settings they use, and use the same version. So I'm not too worried about tying it to a site, since it's just for convenience.

Comment: We discourage language specific challenges when there is no reason for it, but here it is clearly part of the challenge so I see no problem at all.

Comment: Having a fixed number of input bytes to work with can be awkward in language agnostic challenges as it's difficult to choose a suitable number that doesn't make it too difficult / too easy for some languages. Since everyone is using the same language here a fixed 128 bytes seems reasonable. Your examples already show it doesn't need to be higher. You could consider lower, depending on how you want the challenge to go. With 128 bytes there's a good chance some outputs will be too large to fit in the 65536 character answer length limit, but I don't see that as a problem either. Looks good to me

Answer (score 4):

### Castilian Numerals

A little known (but actually real) number system are the Castilian numerals.  They were an odd mix of a digital and positional counting system used in Spain in the late middle ages.  There are certain qualities about them, however, that make them not entirely straight forward to generate when you have lots of them in a group, in particular the fact they would be aligned by thousands places.  Your challenge will be to print a vertical list of numbers, correctly spaced.

### Description of the Numerals

A Castilian numeral is, in effect, a Roman numeral, but only uses 1-999, uses additives for 4 (IIIJ), 9 (VIIIJ), and 900 (DCCCC), and subtractives for 90 (XC) and 400 (CD).  Both methods were commonly used for 40 (XL, XXXX).  Additionally, final Is were written as Js, such that the sequence 1-6 goes J, IJ, IIJ, IIIJ, V, VJ.  (This means standard Roman numeral generators will likely not be much help.)  They were generally written lowercase, but for this challenge we'll use all uppercase.

For values under between 1-999, the fact that the letters indicated numerals was made clear by the presence of a symbol that looks like a U.  Generally the numerals themselves were right aligned:

```
1          U           J
2          U          IJ
999        U DCCCXCVIIIJ
```

For values between 1000-999999, everything we would place to the left of the comma would be rendered as if it were its own independent 3-digit number and romanized, and the reminder placed to the right, such that

```
  1,000    J U
  1,001    J U          J
 21,030  XXJ U        XXX
500,444    D U CDXXXXIIIJ
```

For values 1,000,000-999,999,999, an *additional* separator was used, Q<sup>to</sup>, but for our purposes, we'll just use Q.  It would only be used if the number was over 1,000,000, unlike the U that always separated it.

```
  1,000,000       J Q       U
  1,000,001       J Q       U            J
  1,001,000       J Q     J U
  1,001,001       J Q     J U            J
123,456,789  CXXIIJ Q CDLVJ U DCCLXXXVIIIJ
```

As should be noticed, within each grouping of three (arabic) digits, everything is right aligned, with the thousands/million separators all in alignment.  Because 0 didn't exist, it would just be left blank.

### Input

A sequence of integers in whatever format you feel gives you the best advantage (a list, an array, a series, etc).  You may assume that the integers are between 1 and 999,999,999.

### Output

A printed list of Castilian numerals, properly aligned on different lines.  Note the restrictions on 4/9: mandatory additives are 4,9,900; mandatory subtractives are 90 and 400; 40 is valid either way.  The numerals for 1-999 should be right aligned, with a single space on either side of Q or U (there may be padding spaces, but the single longest numeral in each grouping will have the single space).  Newlines may be whatever is native to your system/language.

### Rules

This is code golf.  Fewest bytes wins.  Standard loopholes forbidden.

### Test cases

Comments/observations are given after `#` and not part of the output.

```
Given: 1,2,3
U   J   
U  IJ
U IIJ   # one space between U and I

Given: 1,1000,10,100
  U J
J U     # trailing space not required
  U X
  U C

Given: 123,4,5678,111111111,90,12345,6789012
                U    CXXIIJ
                U        IV
              V U DCLXXVIIJ   # single space between U and the longest numeral
CXJ Q       CXJ U       CXJ   # Q only appears if >= 10^7
                U        XC
            XIJ U  CCCXXXXV   # also valid CCCXLV 
 VJ Q DCCLXXXIX U       XIJ   # single space between Q and the longest numeral
```

Answer (score 4):

### Polyglot wrappers

Many polyglots are a disastrous mess of unmaintainable code. Let's make this different.

**Challenge**

Make a polyglot "wrapper" such that code from two or more languages may be embedded in the file without modification.

**Example**

Consider the following polyglot wrapper for **Bash and Python**:

```
'''true'
B
exit 0
#'''
P
```

This wrapper can be used such that `B` can be replaced by an arbitrary bash script, and `P` can be replaced by an arbitrary python script.

After the scripts have been injected into the wrapper, running the resulting polyglot via either interpreter (bash or python) will result in functionally identical behavior as the original input scripts.

**Rules**

1. Your wrapper must support the injection of 2 or more languages
2. Your wrapper can use arbitrary markers for the string->script replacement
3. The markers must be at least 1 byte in size (no line number tricks)
4. Assume the replacement will be done by first replacing all markers with sufficiently long and random data, such that conflicts between the marker literals and contents of the input code cannot exist. However, your markers cannot conflict with the contents of the wrapper itself.
5. The behavior of the original input programs must not be altered by the wrapper. Ex: an input program that returns 0 must return 0 when run from your wrapper. An input program that crashes must still crash.
6. The winner is the polyglot wrapper that supports the most languages, with a tie breaker of smallest size (in bytes).
7. Allowances shall be made for a program that accesses itself on disk. Obviously no polyglot wrapper could correctly return identical output for a script that outputs its own file size.

**Question for the sandbox**

Is this sufficiently unique and understandable? Are there any loopholes I haven't covered?

Comment: What if, for example the bash script contains `'''`? Is that what rule 4 is talking about, since I don't really understand that rule.

Comment: I'm indeed wondering the same as @JoKing. What if the content of the code we'd potentially insert into the wrapper contains something that could break the wrapper or other program itself? For example, let's say I submit `0W`, where `0` is a wrapper for a 05AB1E program, and `W` for a Whitespace program. 05AB1E in general ignores all whitespaces between commands and Whitespace ignores all characters except for spaces/tabs/newlines. But what happens if the potential 05AB1E program contains a string with a space/tab/newline in it, which would interfere with the Whitespace program?

Comment: Perhaps make it such that the inner programs are a turing complete subset of the parent language, such that the overall program will always run correctly. Answers would have to make a list of restrictions placed on the language subsets, as well as prove that they are still turing complete, and can't 'break out' of their wrappers, nor have effects on other sections of the program

Comment: Would this work as a cops and robbers? Cops provide wrappers and robbers provide code that breaks the wrappers?

Comment: Good catch, everyone! I'll have to think about this some more. Cops and robbers sounds like a good way to make that problem into a feature, @trichoplax

Comment: Your example can break in a different way too. An unterminated here-doc in bash will continue until the end of the script: `B` =  `cat << EOF`

Answer (score 4):

## [Translate a simple sentence from Toki Pona](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195140/66833)

Comment: _grammatical construct_ - this term seems too general. why not call these _predicate marker_ and _object marker_, or simply "li" and "e" in quotes?

Answer (score 4):

### A Spherical Die

#### Inspiration

I have a [spherical die](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/D06_sphere.jpg), but it's a cheap one so it doesn't work properly. When I roll it, it doesn't always land directly on a "face" marking, but instead can result in an ambiguous result ("is that a 6, a 4 or a 2?")

#### Assumptions

Assume the die is a perfect, evenly-weighted Unit Sphere (i.e. all points on the surface are radius 1cm from the center) , such that a "roll" can result in any point on the sphere being the uppermost point (the "roll value").

Assume that, if the die is placed or rolled such that 1 is at the "north pole", the conventions of a normal die will follow, i.e:

- 6 will be at the "south pole"
- 4, 5, 3, 2 will be on the "equator", clockwise in that order, equidistant around the sphere.

So, before it's rolled, the die looks like this:

[image: image of die]

#### The Challenge

Given a simulated roll of the die (i.e. coordinates representing the top of the die after it's rolled) with the conditions above, identify the closest value (1-6) to that point (i.e. what the roll value should resolve to).

*Input*

A co-ordinate on the sphere.

There are a few co-ordinate systems used for spheres, the two I'm familiar with (and so will provide examples in) are as follows:

- P(1, φ, Θ) where φ is the "azimuth angle" (0..360), Θ is the "polar angle" (0..180)
- P(x,y,z) where \$x^2+y^2+z^2=1\$

(note: the conversion between the two is: x = cos(φ)·sin(Θ); y = sin(φ)·sin(Θ); z = cos(Θ))

for clarity:

- roll "1" is at P(1,n,0)
- roll "2" is at P(1,270,90)
- roll "3" is at P(1,180,90)
- roll "4" is at P(1,0,90)
- roll "5" is at P(1,90,90)
- roll "6" is at P(1,n,180)

*Output*

The nearest value (1-6) to that point. If the point is equidistant to two or more points, output any one of them.

Usual exclusions etc. apply.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [mathematics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)

Comment: Does anyone know the maths for this? Feel free to edit it in!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: You want us to generate a random point on a sphere and output the face of the die it corresponds to?

Comment: yeah, so generate a random point on the sphere, then find the nearest "face" - i.e. the nearest of the 6 points (top, bottom, 4 points on opposite sides around middle)

Comment: This will be exactly equivalent to a uniform distribution over 6 values, just based on the symmetry of the situation.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem yes, all outcomes are equally likely; but the challenge is determining which number any given point on the face of the sphere is closest to

Comment: That's not the challenge as posted. Right now, it's "Takes no input, returns the number the (internally generated) random point is closest to" which is, under the consensus of [no unobservable requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/89287) simply equal to "Takes no input, returns uniform random value from 1-6". If you want the challenge to be "Input is point on sphere, output is number it's closest to", then write that.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I've edited to try and make it clearer what I'm looking for. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It's clearer that my point still stands. Look, "Make Voronoi cells on sphere" and "Generate uniformly random points on sphere" are both good challenges. But when put together like that, they annihilate each other and give you an extremely quick shortcut right from Input (None) to output (a die roll) that doesn't require calculation of either part.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem thanks for the feedback, I'd never heard of a Voronoi cell before. What I'm asking, then, is "generate a random point on a sphere and say which Voronoi cell that point is in". Can you explain why that doesn't work? Note that I'm asking for both the point and the cell to be output, not just the cell - otherwise I agree, given the "no unobservable requirements" rule it would be possible to just generate a random number and pretend you'd done it properly (although that would be against the spirit of it)

Comment: Would it be better for the point on the sphere to be the input, then?

Comment: If you want the challenge to be about finding the points it's closest to, yes.

Comment: I want it to be a good challenge on this theme, whatever that would look like :)

Comment: Although I don't think the current challenge is bad, it's usually best to not have multiple challenges into one nor multiple outputs (since some languages aren't able to output more than once very easily). The two challenges are: 1. Generate a random coordinate on a sphere (in whichever coordinate system you want); 2. Given a (random) coordinate on a sphere, output the dice-value closest to it. No. 1 [already is a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191510/52210), so I agree it might be better to rewrite it to challenge No. 2. I do like the general idea though, so +1 from me.

Comment: It would also need some info about the size of the sphere, and what to do when the coordinate is _exactly_ in the center between two or three poles.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: Nicely reworked. But what is `n` in `roll "1" is at P(1,n,0)`?

Comment: Note that the actual implementation is very simple, as [explained in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54941122#54941122).

Answer (score 4):

## [Hexagonify™ a String Block](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197080/hexagonify-a-string-block) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Answer (score 4):

## Is it a Snake Cube?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

A [*snake cube*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_cube) is a quite popular wooden puzzle. There are usually 27 cubes threaded on an elastic string. Each cube has a hole that either goes straight through from one face to the opposite face, or that makes a 90° bend, that means it exits through a face that is adjecent to the one it enters. (And the two end cubes into which this string enters. Two adjecent cubes on that string can rotate against eachother. The goal is rotating them all such that the whole "snake" forms a large 3x3x3 cube.

[image]
[image]

<sub><sup>Images from Wikipedia [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Snakecube_1.jpg)[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Snakecube_2.jpg)</sup></sub>

Obviously we cannot have any random sequence of the straight/90° pieces if we want to get a cube in the end. This leads us to the

#### Challenge

Given a sequence of the types of the inner 25 cubes of a "snake", determine whether it is possible to form a cube.

## Example

I will here use the symbol **T** for a piece with a straight hole, and **F** for a piece with a 90° hole. The example in the image would be encoded (from the bottom left to the top right) as

```
TFFFTFFTFFFTFTFFFFTFTFTFT
```

#### Details

- You can take the input as a string or list/array or any other type of sequence.
- You can use different symbols for the two types, you could also take booleans or integers.
- The output is also flexible: You're can have two distinct output, one for each case, but they must be consistent. If it is not obvious (e.g. True/False) please specify which one means what.

#### Examples

No cube possible:

```
TFTFTFTFTFTFTFTFFTFFFTFFF (we have 8 consecutive (overlapping) straight runs of length 3)
TFTFTFTFFFFTFTFFFTFFTFFTT (we have a straight run of four pieces at the end)
```

Cube possible:

```
TFFFTFFTFFFTFTFFFFTFTFTFT
TFTFTFTFFFFTFTFFFTFFTFFFT
```

Comment: Oh hey, I have that exact cube, but I forgot how to put it back together again

Comment: @JoKing ...then I should maybe modify the challenge and ask for the solution as output :P

Comment: Don't worry, I dug it out of the drawer it was stuck in and finally solved it

Answer (score 4):

## Rennab

***Reverse banneR***

In the language of your own choosing write a program or function that takes as input the output of the super-handy-for-the-farsighted tool [banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_(Unix)). And simply outputs the original text.

**Example 1a** of `banner` output on Linux:

```
> banner 'Code Golf'

   XXXX              XX                    XXXX            XX       XX
  X    X              X                   X    X            X      X
 X                    X                  X                  X      X
 X        XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX          X        XXXXX     X     XXXX
 X       X     X X    X  X     X         X       X     X    X      X
 X       X     X X    X  XXXXXXX         X   XXX X     X    X      X
 X       X     X X    X  X               X     X X     X    X      X
  X    X X     X X    X  X     X          X    X X     X    X      X
   XXXX   XXXXX   XXXXXX  XXXXX            XXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXX
```

**Example 1b** of `rennab` program that runs on Linux and takes input from `stdin` as lines of strings, and outputs to `stdout`, and supports the characters: `[' ', 'C', 'G', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'l', 'o']`:

```
> banner 'Code Golf' | rennab
Code Golf
```

**Example 2a** of `banner` output on Linux:

```
> banner ':-)'


                   X
                    X
                    X
    X                X
                     X
         XXXXXXX     X
                     X
                     X
    X               X
                    X
                   X
```

**Example 2b** of `rennab` program that runs on Linux and takes input from `stdin` as lines of strings, and outputs to `stdout`, and supports the characters: `[':', '-', ')']`:

```
> banner ':-)' | rennab
:-)
```

Choose what ever characters (minimum of 3)  you want to support but that effects your score (see Rules below).

**Rules**

- Program or function - your choice.
- Input the output of [banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_(Unix)) in whatever format you'd like (*eg* 2d array of characters, list of strings, reading from `stdin` straight from the horse's mouth, *&c*).
- For this challenge we'll use [Cedar Solutions' open-source GNU/GPL banner implementation](http://software.cedar-solutions.com/utilities.html) common on Linux. Prints horizontally only with a fixed size.
- Output the original text in whatever format you'd like, return character at the end optional (*eg* as a string, a list of characters, as output to `stdout`, *&c*).
- You can assume only the characters supported are input.
- You must support a minimum of 3 characters.
- Score is calculated by this formula (where \$n\$ is the number of code bytes and \$c\$ is the number of characters supported): \$n - 8c\$.
- Scores can be negative.
- No standard loopholes.
- Lowest score wins.

**Questions**

- Has this been done before?
- Is the score formula any good? Any and all suggestions welcome.
- Is the question any good? Any and all feedback welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't banner output be rotated 90 degrees? When I was testing `banner`, everything was sideways, not horizontal.

Comment: @Jono2906 The output in my post is copy/pasted straight from my Linux terminal.

Comment: Huh, serves me right for using Unix.

Comment: @Jono2906 Found out there's a few different types of `banner` implementations out there thanks to your comments.  I've picked the one I'm used to and noted that in the post. Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem! I learnt something myself as well (the banner command and also that different OS's implement commands differently).

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54047/42963) is pretty similar, just a different big-character set.

Comment: [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115696/42963) is also really close, with just slight modifications to the big-character set.

Answer (score 4):

### Reversed Iota's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I [didn't](https://github.zhaw.ch/munt/Gulf) invent this challenge, but I find it very interesting to solve.

For every input number, e.g.:

```
4
```

Generate a range from 1 to that number:

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

And then, for every item in that list, generate a list from 1 to that number:

```
[[1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]
```

Then, reverse every item of that list.

```
[[1] [2 1] [3 2 1] [4 3 2 1]]
```

### Notes:

- 1 being a loose item is allowed, since flattening will not matter with this anyway.
- To preserve the spirit of the challenge, the range has to be 1-indexed.

Comment: How should output be formatted?

Comment: [This old challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42536/31625) is pretty similar. The regular challenge isn't really a dupe, but one of the more common ways to get the bonus was to do essentially this. I don't think I would close it because the old one has a bonus, but I can't speak for everyone.

Comment: A naming suggestion: `Reveresed Iota's`

Comment: May the initial `1` be a loose item instead of a list `[1]`? I.e. [3 bytes in Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8o9NiS////mwAA).

Answer (score 4):

## Is it a doubling sequence?

Posted here:

[Is it a doubling sequence?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199409/is-it-a-doubling-sequence)

Comment: Can the input array be empty or of length 1?

Comment: @JoKing In that case, the output must be vacuously `True`, I guess.

Comment: @JoKing good question, I edited the input to only handle arrays with two or more numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### Is it a Happy Number? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

A repost of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/find-whether-a-number-is-happy-or-not) challenge (if I got the policy right).

Given a single *positive* integer (which can also be taken as a list of digits or a string), output whether the number terminates at 1 . Truthy/falsy follows the language's convention, or you can choose exactly one value for truthy and another for falsy. (This sequence is [A007770](https://oeis.org/A007770).)

Your program should theoretically support all non-negative integers; however, if your language doesn't support unbounded integers, you may only support integers up to `2147483647`.

### Procedure

Suppose you have the number `193`.

- Square every individual digit in the number. Therefore the number's individual digits becomes:

```
[1] [81] [9]
```

- Sum all these individual digits:

```
92
```

- Repeat this procedure until it stabilizes at `1` or a 37-cycle like the following:

```
37-58-89-145-42-20-4-16-37
```

It has been shown that the procedure will always produce either one of these two outputs.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsIwFET3OcXQVQJxUVxIhXgCceMJIk31S5PUnwR6@5hacBZ/hvnMo1hrSoyzgXf5FUe5aoEmmuRqTI/IaH487e0mdrlwwPor1O82glxh0z0zhWcLV0oZ3i7SplvxD8dIn2LZjQqpeCWUmCJL0ug1hmFnz20j6U/RHQ4XdHpjk4Ix6BXekQKW9s5zEKrWLw) is a sample program generating the test cases. [Here](https://tio.run/##VY5NCsMgEIX3OcUjKwU3oYuSgjco3fQElph2StR0VPD2qTFQ6FvMz2Pmm6GwbTEyLhrOpleYRFEdqgpWJp8W3zqaRdF6QGDUfDofM7vYpswepRmyxcoTBSbeUyU8a3GlmODMKky8ZfewjPjJhu0kEbOTnezmwIIUBoVxPNhL3RG93tUr0A@n0Mxe4h3I/z2536VK27Yv) is a step by step reduction of all input between 1 and 100.

```
1 -> true
2 -> false
3 -> false
4 -> false
5 -> false
6 -> false
7 -> true
8 -> false
9 -> false
10 -> true
11 -> false
12 -> false
13 -> true
14 -> false
15 -> false
16 -> false
17 -> false
18 -> false
19 -> true
20 -> false
21 -> false
22 -> false
23 -> true
24 -> false
25 -> false
26 -> false
27 -> false
28 -> true
29 -> false
30 -> false
31 -> true
32 -> true
33 -> false
34 -> false
35 -> false
36 -> false
37 -> false
38 -> false
39 -> false
40 -> false
41 -> false
42 -> false
43 -> false
44 -> true
45 -> false
46 -> false
47 -> false
48 -> false
49 -> true
50 -> false
51 -> false
52 -> false
53 -> false
54 -> false
55 -> false
56 -> false
57 -> false
58 -> false
59 -> false
60 -> false
61 -> false
62 -> false
63 -> false
64 -> false
65 -> false
66 -> false
67 -> false
68 -> true
69 -> false
70 -> true
71 -> false
72 -> false
73 -> false
74 -> false
75 -> false
76 -> false
77 -> false
78 -> false
79 -> true
80 -> false
81 -> false
82 -> true
83 -> false
84 -> false
85 -> false
86 -> true
87 -> false
88 -> false
89 -> false
90 -> false
91 -> true
92 -> false
93 -> false
94 -> true
95 -> false
96 -> false
97 -> true
98 -> false
99 -> false
```

Comment: Is there an upper bound for inputs? I think one thing to consider is whether you want answers to implement the square-summing operation, or to try to compress or overfit some heuristic that works for say, 1 to 100.

Comment: Falsy numbers belong to [A007770](https://oeis.org/A007770).

Comment: @Arnauld Nice catch + Title suggestion!

Comment: With the term "happy number" in hand, I found a [probable duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/find-whether-a-number-is-happy-or-not).

Comment: Ugh, why do I always have duplicate ideas recently...

Comment: @xnor This is a dupe indeed, but the other challenge is very old and it seems like it requires a full program with a cumbersome output format. So maybe we should rather close the old challenge as a dupe of this one instead? (I'm not sure about the right policy here.)

Comment: We did once repost [Kolakoski one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157403/78410) and closed the [old one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8369/78410) as dupe (with [relevant meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14871/78410)). But this case is a bit different because the author of the old challenge is no longer active.

Comment: @Arnauld Good point, that old challenge is sure showing its rust.

Answer (score 4):

## Posted

[Solve a Picross Row](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204551/solve-a-picross-row)

Comment: I don't think it is a dupe of full nonogram solver. I recommend allowing flexible I/O formats though (e.g. values other than 0,1,2 to mark each cell state).

Comment: To make the challenge more self-contained, consider adding a brief introduction to picross/nonogram and its rules.

Answer (score 4):

## Implement an HTML renderer [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

**Note:** This challenge explaination is very much incomplete - it merely contains ideas that will require revising to form a proper challenge post.

The premise of the challenge is to write a program that take an HTML document as an input, and outputs an ASCII equivalent. Obviously, working with real HTML is not possible, so this challenge will use a *very limited* and *modified* subset of HTML.

Here is an example of a potential input:

```
<body>
    <h1>A Document</h1>
    <div>
        <span>Hello, this is some text</span>
        <img> 8 2 </img>
    </div>
</body>
```

Which would yield the following output:

```
+--------------------+
|A DOCUMENT          |
|                    |
|+------------------+|
||Hello, this is som||
||e text            ||
||+--------+        ||
|||@~@~@~@~|        ||
|||~@~@~@~@|        ||
||+--------+        ||
|+------------------+|
+--------------------+
```

### HTML elements that will be implemented:

**<span>** - Renders text between the tags, wrapping when necessary.

Example:

```
<body>
<span>
    This is a span element.
    You can write text in here.
</span>
</body>
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|This is a span eleme|
|nt. You can write te|
|xt in here.         |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

(Extra explanation needed to clarify whitespace and character set issues)

**<p>** (Explanations are omitted to save space)

**<h1>** - **<h6>**

**<div>**

**<img>**

### Sandbox questions/remakrs

- I believe it is possible to write an unambiguous and specific set of rules for how an "HTML document" should be rendered
- It will require lots of careful explanation, wording, and ample examples
- However this challenge seems very long and complicated and it seems like it might not be in the spirit of a code golf challenge

What do you guys think?

Comment: "I believe it is possible" -- Yes, rewriting a subset of the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) for ASCII is possible. However, successful challenges tend to keep it simple. I'd suggest using just `span` and `div` and using no attributes. In addition, parsing has probably been done before and is [cumbersome](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/68261), so I'd suggest allowing input as a pre-parsed AST to focus on the key challenge of ASCII-art generation

Comment: Personally I would keep only `body`, `div`, `span` and `img`, altho `img` should follow a set pattern inside of it. I would also suggest making height and width attributes mandatory, in all tags.

Answer (score 4):

## [Solve a 2xN Maze (posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206957/solve-a-2xn-maze)

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 4):

## Does the naïve fill suffice?

A bot is positioned in a rectangular grid. By preference it will paint in a west direction, but if it cannot it will paint in a south, east or if all else fails north direction. Sometimes this can lead it to fill the grid, but other times it gets stuck. The following examples show how the path (indicated by ascending digits) of the bot on a given grid varies depending on its starting position:

```
1
```

The bot is always able to fill a `1×1` grid, since simply by existing it has already painted the grid.

```
14    21    43    34
23    34    12    21
```

The bot is always able to fill a `2×2` grid. As a consequence of its painting direction preferences it normally traverses anticlockwise except when it starts in the bottom right corner when it traverses clockwise.

```
16    21    65    ..    56    65    165    216    321    654     345    456
25    36    14    21    43    34    234    345    456    123     216    321
34    45    23    34    12    21
```

The bot usually fills a `2×3` grid, except when it starts in the middle right square. On the other hand, it always fills a `3×2` grid; its painting direction preferences cause it to paint clockwise if it starts in the bottom middle or bottom right cell, otherwise anticlockwise.

```
189    21.    321    87.    987    ...    987    ...    987
276    387    498    165    216    321    236    345    456
345    456    567    234    345    456    145    216    321
```

The bot is able to fill a `3×3` grid when it starts in one of the even squares. It's mathematically impossible for the bot to fill it when it starts in an odd square, but I have included these positions for completeness.

Your task is to solve the [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) of whether the bot is able to fill a given grid from a given starting point. You can assume that the grid size is a positive integer and that the starting point lies within the grid. You can take the grid size and starting point in any consistent order, as separate inputs, a pair of pairs or a list of 4 elements, or any other reasonable input format. The starting point can be 0-indexed or 1-indexed. You can use any two consistent outputs, or you can output using any values that your language considers truthy or falsy, but not both. Please include your input and output format in your answer.

The directions west, south, east or north correspond to decrementing the x-coordinate, incrementing the y-coordinate, incrementing the x-coordinate and decrementing the y-coordinate respectively.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Test cases (0-indexed, width height x y):

```
4 4 0 0 -> True
4 4 1 1 -> False
4 4 2 2 -> True
4 4 3 3 -> True
4 7 1 3 -> False
```

Comment: What's the "naive fill" algorithm exactly?

Comment: Comment: it's hard for me to figure out that each "column" (separated by space) represents a x*y board. Consider clarifying that.

Comment: @user202729 The very first two sentences are supposed to describe it, just move in the first available preferred direction until you can't move any more and paint as you go.

Comment: Some comments: (1) You don't seem to define that "naïve fill" is. (2) It took me a while to undersdtand the meaning of the numbers `14, `21` etc mean the 2nd example, and similarly in others. After a while I realized that each "code section" contains _several_ examples stacked horizontally. You should make thast more obvious (maybe increasing horizontal space, or explaining it in the text)

Comment: (3) "It normally traverses anticlockwise except when it starts in the bottom right corner when it traverses clockwise": what does "normally" mean here? How do we know/choose the direction the robot follows? Or maybe _this_ is the definition of "naïve fill"? (4) Why can't the robot fill the `2×3` case when it starts in the middle right square? That is, why doesn't start by moving up instead of left? (5) In general, but I find it all quite confusing... maybe it's me, but consider explaining the challenge with more detail

Comment: @LuisMendo (1) The bot paints as it goes. It prefers to go west, but when it can't go west tries south, then east, then north. That's all there is to it. (2) I've added some more text and spacing. (3) "normally" means "most of the time it ends up doing this". (4) Because its first preferred direction is west so it ends up painting itself into a corner.

Comment: (1) _It prefers to go west, but when it can't go west tries south, then east, then north._ That phrasing makes it much totally clear. (Now I see that's probably what you meant with _by preference_) Include it in the text? (3) I still find the word _normally_ confusing there, as if that were an additional degree of freedom. Also, I see now that _except when it starts in the bottom right corner when it traverses clockwise_ is a consequence of (1). I suggest you explicitly state something like "As a consequence of the rule for direction choice, ..."

Comment: @LuisMendo Fair enough; I've tweaked the text again now.

Comment: I really like this challenge, but I wonder whether the title could be a little more descriptive/catchy - perhaps 'Can the bot fill the grid?' or similar?

Comment: @Dingus "Can the naïve bot fill the grid?" counts as similar, right?

Comment: Ooh, that's even better. Immediately makes me curious to find out what the naïve bot is.

Answer (score 4):

## Stroke Count of a Chinese Numeral [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210107/81203)

Comment: [Related (not dupe)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/97734/78410). Stroke count is actually good idea because it avoids the need to hardcode Chinese characters. The description looks clear enough to me.

Comment: Might be useful: https://tio.run/##TZLBSsNAEIbP5imGXNqilE2ySZOCTyIKkqQY1KQkESkitBSRQr31IqFPIF6l7UFfRhGfIv6bzW6bU7@dmX9m/ul4Ul5lqVPX0emDYf5VH@bQZERknhjm92YKshTtliBbxxYgp6WfqgJxnbkCuSr29A7ydN0cNNCxN5CvYts1KFCxl5noziT9vn42xNrYXBKTms8NXXDZ/UuSD3o0kttxlpdUTApjlOUUUpIK6BdllKT9PL6Mur2hcdQ@ZXdl/z5PyrgbnYXneMmTcbd33KEOJSNZHFF8U8QU9uqa9l9KhOTsOi6IwqskjYvYOAhjC8tpf8Pkg5BY0FaAnfch24Fp1qAl2A8PYDtyYKlOGzCOC9meStvMYQ5a4CTIxAkN1Ud8RO5BLxjXRn2PcR8DcjUKLiMbIUeqobt8xAyyigfcchkGdHVVk4Y7itqqQi0GwDz4R@AdOhivqXUxjhXY@Mc4vl5wJTI302ZNVbhdC9wtpaDRLOIyj7tWIHbXW09xdqGvGsnJGxPa7o3gDIJCxBFmcMbghmNpkQVEZImU@gc

Comment: (to read the test cases)

Comment: Has it been posted to main? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @V.Courtois posted.

Answer (score 4):

Note: this challenge is a work-in-progress, so suggestions would be appreciated

Questions for meta:

- How can I prevent people from just using SHA or MD5 one-way compression?
- are these language restrictions fair?
- is this scoring system fair?
- are there any obvious cheap answers?
- what other tags should be added?
- what should the challenge title be?
- will these restrictions adequately prevent people trying to cheat their way through?
- should a limit be put on a password length? Should I limit passwords to ASCII printable characters?

## The challenge

Your challenge is to first choose a "password" (please do not use your actual password). Then, you will create a program which will output a truthy value if and only if this password is given as input, falsy otherwise. Your goal will be to make it so others are unable to reverse-engineer this password (and you will keep this password secret for now).

## Scoring

The scoring for this challenge is somewhat different than regular [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). During the first two weeks from when an answer is posted, other users will have the opportunity to try to crack your password by reverse-engineering your code. If anyone gets your password correct during this two week period, your answer will be marked as cracked. If two weeks pass without users finding the password, your answer can be marked as safe once you share the password (again, please do not use your actual password, you should make up a new one that you don't use anywhere).

Note that you may use any tools at your disposal (online tools, brute-force attacks, modified code, etc) to extract someone else's password from their code.

Of all the safe answers, the one with the shortest source code (i.e. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)) wins!

## Rules

To make things fair for everyone, you may only use languages that appear on [TIO](https://tio.run/#), or languages that have well-written documentation and are used somewhat widely. You must also provide a link to try your code online that anyone can access (as such, you may not use languages behind paywalls like MATLAB but Octave is still on the table because it's free).

Even if you don't want to post an answer, feel free to try to crack any of the existing answer's passwords! If you get a password, you can simply leave a comment on that answer and that answer will be cracked.

## Note

If you edit the code in your answer, the two week period will reset! You may edit any explanations in your answer freely (I will verify that any answers marked safe did not cheat).

tags: code-golf

Comment: [Example answer](https://tio.run/##Vc3BCgIhEIDh8/oUkx1S6tDWqci69gYRdJHWckBGGbXo6a2l014/fvjTp/hI2za/xroIAci9HMOzupyheAfJ5vyOPMyaNUipFqUFmrV4RIa7twxIYPeiw6X5VWok3YnESEWhMX2/2YGlAexBnl0IcQWXyGG4Sfnn44RBatEajmuc/k9f "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Surely any cryptographic hash function (which are implemented in many languages) will make it easy to generate an impossible-to-crack answer?  For instance, in R I can write ```test=scan(,'');if(digest::digest(test,"md5")=="b6778692586dc649267723ccc3356fad")TRUE else FALSE``` and I'll be pretty confident that nobody will crack my password...

Comment: That is a good point. It seems like this challenge is similar to just writing a hash function. You might want to add other ideas to make the challenge more interesting

Comment: That's what I was about to write, any hash function with a hidden default salt depending on the language, or anything like that, could be hiding the password easily enough.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen is this an actual MD5 hash? I was unable to reverse it (note that a lot of MD5 hashes can be reversed with [online tools like this](http://reversemd5.com/)). Note that for this challenge people would be allowed any and all tools at their disposal to crack passwords. This means people are very much allowed to reverse-engineer code in any ways they please

Comment: Answering in many esolangs could hide the password easily enough, too. If I answer in Lenguage, Unary, Mariolang,...

Comment: @V.Courtois this is true, but the point is not to read the password in the source code. The point of the challenge would be to reverse-engineer their code to crack a password (so documentation and online tools are all fair game). Also, Unary will likely be an invalid language because people must be able to actually run the program online (and Unary programs are usually way too big to run online)

Comment: Now that I think about it, any type of loop could hide the password easily enough, too. But even with what I said before and what I'm saying now, I think this challenge has to exist (if not existing already), because having many valid answers is not a problem (not to me, at least).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen also, even if nobody can reverse your password, that's still fine - the winner of this challenge is whoever has the shortest code out of all the uncracked passwords. In other words, this is still a codegolf challenge, but answers can be disqualified if anyone finds the password. So, if you want to win but you don't have the shortest code, you simply have to crack other people's passwords!

Comment: @DanielH. Yes, my example was an actual MD5 hash (the password was ```mypassword```).  You're right that some hash functions can be reversed, but there are many cryptographically-secure ones for which this is difficult.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'm unfamiliar with MD5 hashes, but when I converted `mypassword` to an MD5 hash using three different online tools I got `34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44` every time instead of the hash in your answer. Could you please provide a TIO link for the R code (when I copy-pasted it into TIO it didn't work for me and I'm unfamiliar with R)? I'd like to try experimenting with MD5

Comment: I'm afraid that the R 'digest' library is not installed on TIO (making a link was the first thing I tried).

Comment: But, after some research, it turns-out that R adds some (consistent) extra characters to the string by default before applying MD5.  This behaviour can be switched off, at which point ```mypassword``` indeed hashes to ```34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44```.

Comment: how many letters are the passowrds capped at? Are unprintables allowed?

Comment: @Razetime I might add a restriction of 16 characters, ASCII printables only. I will have to try to balance this cap though - if it's too short, passwords can easily be brute-forced. If it's too long, everyone will just use one-way compression and passwords will never be cracked

Comment: Perhaps some kind of no-builtins rule could work here, since the code for MD5 or SHA will be very long?

Comment: @user253751 I agree that a no builtins rule here would be a good thing, but a lot of users tend to downvote immediately upon seeing a builtin ban of any kind regardless of how much it helps the question. Take for example [this question of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206257/find-the-date-that-is-n-days-from-january-1st-1984) which was closed because of the builtin ban but later reopened by people who actually read the question (I made zero changes to the original rules)

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography might also make for easy-to-make hard-to-break programs. Encrypt input with the public key and check against should-be-result, like you would with a hash

Answer (score 4):

#### All work and no play but it gets thinner every time

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Your objective is to output the unique string with the following properties:

- Each paragraph consists entirely of repetitions of the sentence `All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.`
- The first paragraph is a single line with exactly one repetition of the sentence.
- Each line of each subsequent paragraph is shorter than the longest line of the previous paragraph.
- Each line contains as many words of the sentence as possible without exceeding the length limit, and no trailing whitespace.
- Paragraph ends when its next line would be identical of some previous line of the same paragraph, possibly terminating the last sentence early.
- The last paragraph has the same width as the longest word in the sentence (5).
- There's a pair of line ends between each pair of paragraphs, a single line end after the last paragraph, and no line end before the first paragraph.

The string produced by these rules has: 5025 bytes when using Windows line ends (CR LF) or 4796 bytes using Linux line ends (LF); 229 line ends; 103 full repetitions of the sentence and 11 partial repetitions. It can be compressed into a 249-byte deflate stream (bubblegum code). The full string is included below for reference.

```
All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack
a dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull

All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes Jack
a dull boy. All work and no play

All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All

All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a

All work and no play makes Jack
a dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play

All work and no play makes Jack
a dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work and
no play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All work
and no play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play makes

All work and no play
makes Jack a dull boy.

All work and no play
makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and no
play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work
and no play makes
Jack a dull boy. All
work and no play

All work and no
play makes Jack a
dull boy. All work
and no play makes
Jack a dull boy.

All work and no
play makes Jack a
dull boy. All
work and no play
makes Jack a dull
boy. All work and
no play makes
Jack a dull boy.

All work and no
play makes Jack
a dull boy. All
work and no play
makes Jack a
dull boy. All

All work and no
play makes Jack
a dull boy. All
work and no

All work and
no play makes
Jack a dull
boy. All work
and no play
makes Jack a
dull boy. All
work and no
play makes

All work and
no play
makes Jack a
dull boy.

All work
and no play
makes Jack
a dull boy.

All work
and no
play makes
Jack a
dull boy.

All work
and no
play
makes
Jack a
dull boy.

All work
and no
play
makes
Jack a
dull
boy. All
work and
no play

All
work
and no
play
makes
Jack a
dull
boy.

All
work
and
no
play
makes
Jack
a
dull
boy.
```

Comment: So a sentences can span one or more lines? Was thinking the sentences got shorter until you said there's 103 full repetitions. No clear explanation on what exactly paragraphs, paragraph widths, sentences, lines, and line ends are.

Comment: @Noodle9 I've added some of the reference output; would the reference suffice to explain those?

Comment: Can you simply add the whole output? (I still don't understand it)

Comment: @thedefault. added. I didn't want to clutter the sandbox.

Comment: Alternative name: Write a novel for Jack Torrance

Comment: Better to say what *you* mean by these terms. Maybe a template of the output where lines are, say, seperared by newline characters. Sentences are substring of "..." containing only whole words and ended by a period. Paragraphs are seperated by two newlines. Or whatever it actually is.

Answer (score 4):

## Make a quine that shrinks and grows

Write a program that outputs another program that is:

- Larger in bytes than the original
- Outputs a program that is smaller than itself that also obeys these rules and is larger than the original program

Basically the output should alternate between larger than the previous program and smaller than it, while increasing in total size as it goes.

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21831/76162)

Comment: Perhaps it should be "larger than the program two before" rather than "larger than the original?" As stated, a 5-length program could output a 7-length, which outputs a 6-length, which then oscillates between 7 and 6, not growing in total size as it goes.

Comment: Probably should be named something other than a quine because I find that term misleading for the challenge you described.

Answer (score 4):

## Strobogrammatic Numbers

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

#### Definition

A number which is rotationally symmetrical, i.e., it'll appear the same when rotated by 180 deg in the plane of your screen. The following figure illustrates it better,

[image: strobogrammatic-number]

(source: w3resource.com)

## Task

Given a number as the input, determine if it's strobogrammatic or not.

## Examples

- Truthy

```
1
8
0
69
96
69169
1001
666999
888888
101010101
```

- Falsey

```
2
3
4
5
7
666
969
1000
88881888
969696969
```

## Rules

- The number is guaranteed to be less than a billion.
- We are considering `1` in it's roman numeral format for the sake of the challenge.
- Input can be taken as number, or an array of chars, or as string.
- Output would be a truthy/falsey value.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

---

## Meta

- Although I've tried a search, but is this a duplicate?
- Is the challenge's text clear enough?
- Any tricky/interesting test case?

Comment: [Similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62183/will-it-ambigram)

Answer (score 4):

## [Interpret Interval Notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217297/66833)

Comment: @Adám  yes to `∪` and `-`ish characters. I also broadened the scope to all meaningful intervals, so ranges may overlap and `[5,5]` (all integers `x` where `5<=x<=5`)is `[5]` but not `[5,5)` (all integers `x` where `5<=x<5`) and `(5,5)` (all integers `x` where`5<x<5`) are undefined.

Comment: All integers `x` where `5<=x<5` would be `[]`, no?

Comment: I'd put all the undefined cases separately, or at least at the end.

Comment: Typo: the `[9,13]` test case should either be `[9,13)` or `13` is missing from the output.

Comment: `undefined` cases should be _undefined behavior_ instead. Otherwise, one need to handle it separately which feels bad. Otherwise, it's a good challenge :)

Comment: If you allow other symbols for the brackets, make sure to prohibit other *phrases* as that can be abused.

Comment: @Adám what do you mean by *phrases*?

Comment: @pxeger Multi-character constructs. It'd allow solutions to require an input format that contained the necessary code such that the solution becomes an eval.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/172922/80214)

Comment: Is parsing a string necessary? Could you also allow other constructs (tuples with a marker to show if they're open or closed)?

Comment: Just asking frankly, did you forgot to post this, or is something yet missing?

Comment: @user I am going to say no to other constructs otherwise, it is basically a duplicate of the related challenge.

Comment: @vrintle Something like that. I haven't really been active since just before Christmas. I'll probably post it this afternoon.

Answer (score 4):

## Explain a Code Golf Answer [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Background

When writing Code Golf answers, it is often a good idea to add an explanation of the code so the reader understands what's going on. For example, this [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216665) by [@Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/94066) (abridged):

```
        θ  # last element of
Σ          # the input, sorted in increasing order by
     1¢    # the number of ones of
   %       # modulo
 žJ        # 4294967296
    b      # in binary
```

The full program is written on the first line, then a blank line, then on each successive line, a little snippet of the program, aligned using spaces with its position in the full program, and then some comments on the right-hand side explaining each part.

I, for one, find writing and aligning these explanations tedious, so let's outsource it to a program.

### Task

Given a program as a string, and a list of sets of pairs of start/end indices to form an inclusive range, output each sub-string defined by the indices on a new line, indented to its respective position in the whole string, with a `#` at the end of the line, padded so that there are two spaces before the `#` after the last sub-string, ready for the user to add their explanation.

### Rules

- You may use 0-based or 1-based indexing
- You are guaranteed to receive valid, non-overlapping ranges, which together cover the whole string
- You may assume the program string contains no newlines, tabs or other unprintable characters, and no double-width characters
- Standard [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) and [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) apply
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins

### Examples (1-based indexing)

Inputs: `abcdwxyz`, `(1-8)`
Output:

```
abcdwxyz  #
```

Inputs: `abcdwxyz`, `(5-7)`,  `(1-2),(8-8)`,  `(3-4)`
Output:

```
    wxy   #
ab     z  #
  cd      #
```

Inputs: `<<<$[grep -c wx $0-grep -c y\z $0];:<<'Q'`, `(6-20)`,  `(22-37)`,  `(4-5),(38-38),(21-21)`,  `(1-3)`,  `(39-39)`,  `(40-40)`,  `(41-45)]`
Output:

```
     `grep -c wx $0`                           #
                     `grep -c y\z $0`          #
   $[               -                ]         #
<<<                                            #
                                      ;        #
                                       :       #
                                        <<'Q'  #
```

---

## Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49016/code-explanation-formatter)

Comment: @Razetime I would say this is a dupe :-(

Comment: I'd say this is simpler and more suited for code golf because it functions without the need for a complex priority system. You may want to request more opinions on the nineteenth byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Implement a zipwith function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218017/implement-a-zipwith-function)

Comment: APL or J will win this with 2 bytes (that's the shortest possible score, right?)

Comment: Required tag: [tag:restricted-source]

Comment: Why the builtin restriction?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms [To avoid trivialising the challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216734/jellys-untruth#comment505940_216734)

Comment: @Adám 1) if those 2 bytes are a builtin, then no, otherwise, very possible. 2) Why [restricted-source]?

Comment: Any reason for banning that builtin in Haskell and Jelly? What's wrong with people submitting that as answer? They won't get upvoted much anyway. And it still lets people use builtins in other languages.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing No, that'd be prohibited by your source restrictions rule on an exact built-in. Rather, it'd be a more general built-in (so not "*exact*") plus a parameter that makes the general built-in choose the required behaviour.

Comment: Allowing the built-in and seeing how many languages have it could be interesting in its own right. Or, generalize the problem to `nzipwith`, which takes an n-ary function and n sequences (and optionally the value n) and call the function for each n-tuple from the n sequences.

Comment: I've softened the builtin ban to simply encourage people to post a non-builtin answer as well. @Bubbler Possibly, but I think it'd be a good challenge to simply have the basic `zipwith` given that it's a fairly common functional programming construct

Comment: I think it's better to not ban them, and simply let builtin users wallow in their downvotes/shame so they don't do it again

Comment: @pxeger I've removed the builtin ban, and changed it to encourage builtin-only answers to include a non-builtin version as well

Comment: Would taking input as two lazily evaluated iterators over the elements of the list or outputting an iterator over the results be acceptable

Comment: @Aiden4 I think that taking lists as lazy iterators is an accepted I/O method, so yes

Comment: I find the former ban on Jelly's `"` interesting considering that there's no way to really *pass* it a function.

Answer (score 4):

## Calculate the 'geothmetic meandian' of a set of numbers

Randall Munroe's March 10 xkcd comic ["Geothmetic Meandian"](https://xkcd.com/2435/) defines the 'geothmetic meandian' of a set of positive real numbers as follows.

> Define a function F, such that F accepts a set of *n* positive real numbers and returns the set (*a*, *b*, *c*), where *a* is the arithmetic mean of the set (the sum of the numbers in the set divided by *n*), *b* is the geometric mean of the set (the product of the numbers in the set to the power of *1/n*), and *c* is the median of the set (the average of the middle two numbers in the sorted set when *n* is even, and the middle number in the set when *n* is odd). The function F can therefore be applied again to its own output. Iterating F an infinite number of times should cause its three outputs to converge to one value *g*. This value *g* is defined as the *geothmetic meandian* of the original set of positive reals. (For the purposes of this challenge, you may assume this value exists and does not diverge.)

Given a nonempty list of positive real numbers in any convenient and reasonable format and a positive integer *q*, compute its 'geothmetic meandian' to *q* [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, and the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[[1], 2] --> 1.0
[[2, 8], 4] --> 4.742
[[1, 1, 2, 3, 5], 6] --> 2.08906
[[1, 2, 4, 8], 6] --> 3.13227
[[1.1, 2.2, 4.4, 8.8], 9] --> 3.44550208
```

Comment: This seems like a decent challenge, but I don't know if the rounding requirement adds anything.

Comment: @rak1507 I was accounting for if different languages have different levels of floating-point precision, and also because the calculation needs to stop at some defined point.

Comment: The problem with taking the number of significant figures `q` as input is that you're banning the use of float and double numbers entirely (doubles will break at `q >= 16` or so), which is a big no-no. You could take the number of iterations `i` instead and require the solutions to output the result of `i`-th iteration.

Comment: @Bubbler I envisioned part of the challenge to be determining when to stop the iteration of F. Should I then restrict `q` to be a positive integer from `1` to `7` or something similar?

Comment: Alternatively, we can have have a fixed number of iterations `i` and output the geothmetic meandian to the highest precision possible given `i` iterations. However, thinking about it, I agree this part of the challenge may be unfeasible.

Comment: Oh dear. I just tried another test case and due to floating-point errors in calculation, my program slowly drifts by `2e-12` indefinitely as F is iterated...

Comment: How about this: Given a value `q` (a positive floating-point number), stop iteration when the difference between the maximum and the minimum is less than `q`, and output any of the three numbers (or all of them). Allow the solutions to fail if `q` is too small compared to the input (i.e. it is outside the precision capability of the floating-point type in use). I think this is clearer to specify the error margin this way.

Comment: Or just require that all programs use a fixed `q`, e.g. 100?

Comment: I feel like adding anything to do with the precision will just complicate things, and most of the code will be for handling that, not for actually answering the challenge. IMO it's fine to say 'until it converges', and leave specifics up to the challenge answerers.

Answer (score 4):

## Hide a message in ASCII art and an image

(needs cooler title)

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [steganography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography)

---

## [Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223160/45613)

---

## [Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223158/45613)

Comment: How the heck?! I was just drafting a challenge about stenography and images yesterday and then I see this..

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms was your idea the exact same as mine?

Comment: Not identical, there was no ASCII art included, but considering there are only 5 steganography questions on the whole site that's an insane coincidence

Comment: If the robber doesn’t know any of the messages, it might be hard to verify any potential explanation. It might be more fun and easier to verify a correct solution if the cop posts N codes and the solutions to N-1 of them, and the robber has to use those to reverse engineer the method and decode the last one. Alternately, the cop could have to pick from a list of pre-selected messages so the robber has some idea what to look for.

Comment: Do the ascii+png files have to contain all the information necessary for decoding? For example, could I use a book cipher where the PNG encodes word numbers, and you then have to look up the corresponding words from The Great Gatsby?

Comment: @water_ghosts I think a book cipher should only be allowed if you provide a link to the book. All data needed to decode aside from the image and ascii art should be present in the post and be constant across all encodings.

Comment: This is amazing! You, dear sir/ma'am, get an upvote

Answer (score 4):

## [Determine Circles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223362/determine-circles)

Comment: Nice idea, but could you make it clearer what do you mean by cross? A test case would be good.

Comment: @math intersect or some concept like that. Can you give some better wording if you can understand what I mean? I can't find any word that suit *line go over dot*

Comment: Maybe: 1, 2, 3 points will need 1 circle only to be sure that the points touch the circles boundary? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Some testcases are definitely needed, like five points on one circle and three points on another. Also, are the coordinates integers or real numbers?

Comment: @Bubbler Real number I think

Comment: @okie Then you need to explicitly write it down, and add some testcases with non-integer coordinates.

Comment: In this problem, the answer does not change continuously with small perturbations of the input coordinates. Is it allowed to output the wrong answer due to floating point errors? For instance, if the input coordinates were `(0,0),(0.3,0.3),(1,1)` then the output should be `2`. However, if the second point were instead `(0.3,0.300...00001)` then the answer should be `1`. Given that floating point types are usually unable to tell these two cases apart, are we allowed to output either `1` or `2`?

Comment: @Delfad0r Thanks for your help. To solve such problem (float precision), I decided to add a limit to float so that precision are not extreme.

Comment: Another possible approach (which I personally prefer, but the choice is entirely up to you) could be to only have integer coordinates as input, and then ask for an exact solution. If I am not mistaken, this problem should be solvable without resorting to square roots and similar, and therefore without any possibility of floating point errors.

Comment: @Delfad0r But it's like a `float *100` `0.03*100 = 30` which just get every number bigger?

Comment: @okie Yes, but the difference is that computations with integers are exact, while computations with floats are not. It shouldn't matter too much however, do whatever you prefer :)

Comment: @Delfad0r I think I would take Integer, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [posted lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223880/print-every-code-golf-tag)

Comment: Another suggestion it can be kolmogorov complexity challe ge too, if someone downloads tags and compresses the text

Comment: @Wasif it's better as an internet challenge because a new tag might be created after challenge posting making the list invalid.

Comment: Should the list include the synonym tags, i.e. the tags that are listed as being on no questions in the tag listing?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing if it is listed on the tags page, then it needs to be included

Comment: What is the 43 for in example program?

Comment: @tsh 43 is the number of occurrences of `tag` when you try and access a page of tags that doesn't exist

Comment: Rule is still too wide, everyone can upload code to `codegolf.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @l4m2 if people include all the tags in a post, then they will have to a) keep it constantly updated (which wouldn't be viewed favourably by the community) and b) withstand potential downvotes for loop holing on both the answer to this and the answer that has the tags

Answer (score 4):

## [Implement an Over function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223881/implement-an-over-function)

Comment: Can we take \$a\$ and \$b\$ as `[a,b]`? In effect, this would make the challenge a \$g\$ reduction of \$f\$ mapped over that input list.

Comment: @Adám I think it would be unfair (and potentially unobservable) to ban languages from taking it as `[a,b]`, and doing so would likely just create solutions in the form `pair input; map f; reduce g`

Answer (score 4):

[Do I need a win streak?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224349/77516)

Comment: taking `P` as a fraction seems fine, but it seems more convenient separately since we're just supposed to increment N and P till the desired ratio is achieved. What is the allowance for floating point errors on this question?

Comment: an additional "Streak bonus" for every x games might be an interesting addition.

Comment: @Razetime Oh did I say fraction, I meant a decimal value between 0 and 1, eg: 0.53 for 53%. There wont be more than two decimal places in the input so I doubt if any language will run into floating point errors at all.

Comment: I updated the question to allow `P` as decimal. About the streak bonus, I think it might complicate things quite a bit so I am not going with that.

Comment: You should clarify in the text if the inputs `W`, `N` can be taken separately or only as one number corresponding to `W/N`. And if so, please address Razetime's comment on floating point errors

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, taking them separately is fine. I updated the post again, please check if it is clear now.

Comment: I'd suggest also allowing languages to take `P` as a fraction. Other than that, this looks good to go

Comment: I think they _have_ to be taken separately. In the first example, if you take `W/N` as `0.2` you cannot compute the output, because you don't know if `W=1, N=5`, or `W=2,N=10`, or...

Comment: Oh yes, you're right about that. You'd have to consider both the values to calculate the answer.

Comment: @LuisMendo But if it somehow benefits you to take it say as a string of the form "W/N" with the original values of W and N, then that's fine too. I think the rules clarify that point.

Answer (score 4):

### Death-onacci sequence (WIP)

The traditional Fibonacci sequence grows forever:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ... 1,346,269 ...
```

and is given by this formula:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

where the initial numbers in the sequence are `0, 1`.

However, there's a set of as-yet unnamed sequences, where a previous number 'dies' and is removed from the total.

For instance the sequence for the 5th death-onacci (m = 5) is given by

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3) + f(n-4) - f(n-5)
```

And the first m-1 numbers is 0, followed by a single 1 (so for m=5 the sequence start `0 0 0 0 1`)

Test cases:

Here are some test cases:

| n | f(n), m=3 | f(n), m=4 | f(n), m=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 | 11 | 8 |
| 9 | 4 | 19 | 14 |
| 10 | 5 | 32 | 27 |
| 11 | 5 | 56 | 51 |
| 12 | 6 | 96 | 96 |
| 13 | 6 | 165 | 180 |
| 14 | 7 | 285 | 340 |
| 15 | 7 | 490 | 640 |
| 16 | 8 | 844 | 1205 |
| 17 | 8 | 1454 | 2269 |
| 18 | 9 | 2503 | 4274 |
| 19 | 9 | 4311 | 8048 |
| 20 | 10 | 7424 | 15156 |
| 21 | 10 | 12784 | 28542 |
| 22 | 11 | 22016 | 53751 |
| 23 | 11 | 37913 | 101223 |
| 24 | 12 | 65289 | 190624 |
| 25 | 12 | 112434 | 358984 |
| 26 | 13 | 193620 | 676040 |
| 27 | 13 | 333430 | 1273120 |
| 28 | 14 | 574195 | 2397545 |
| 29 | 14 | 988811 | 4515065 |
| 30 | 15 | 1702816 | 8502786 |
| 31 | 15 | 2932392 | 16012476 |

You must write a function or program that takes one number M, and prints out the first 31 M-Death-onacci numbers. M will be a whole number larger than 0 and less than 31. The output can be in any human readable format, and you can take input in any reasonable manner. (Command line arguments, function arguments, STDIN, etc.)

As usual, this is Code-golf, so standard loopholes apply and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Very similar.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70476/print-the-n-bonacci-sequence)

Comment: @Razetime definitely, but hopefully different enough?

Comment: Well, it's a WIP. You can go ahead and add more details which distinguish it. 'tis the sandbox, after all.

Comment: @Razetime how's it looking now?

Comment: looks better, and the tests are more comprehensive. I suggest posting in TNB for other people's feedback.

Answer (score 4):

## Solve the halting problem for ^/a*b*/b*a*/[ab]*$ in /// [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)
[halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem)

[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), a.k.a. Slashes is an esoteric programming language with simple two operations. One is to output its source to remove from it. The other is to substitute itself. The language is proven to be Turing-complete, so some programs such as `/ab/bbaa/aab` won't halt while some such as `/ab/bbaa/ab` will.

At first I questioned if halting problem for `^/[ab]*/[ab]*/[ab]*$` is solvable, but [I learned unlikely](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/142025/139273).

So I am simplying to `^/a*b*/b*a*/[ab]*$`.

## Problem

Given a slashes program that matches `^/a*b*/b*a*/[ab]*$` in POSIX BRE (i.e. below), determine whether the program halts or not.

### Format of program, if you are not familiar with POSIX BRE

```
program = "/" first "/" second "/" third
first = "" | first "a" | first first.b
first.b = "" | first.b "b"
second = "" | second "b" | second second.a
second.a = "" | second.a "a"
third = "" | third "a" | third "b"
```

## Constrains

In this problem every program's length is up to 153.

## Detailed rules

- Can be either a full program or a function.
- Standard i/o apply.

  - Examples of input format

    - a string of program
    - three strings p,q,r when the program is `/p/q/r`
    - integers p,q,r,s and a string t when the program is `/a\{p\}b\{q\}/b\{r\}a\{s\}/t`
    - entirely as an integer (think of it by yourself)
  - Examples of output format

    - zero or one
    - string
    - [**by halting or not is not an option**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12317/100411)
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest code wins.

## Examples

[Testcase generator 1](https://tio.run/##bVC7DoIwFN37FU0XWoUI7gw0IcZBYyI/UB5qo7mYtoSB8O1IBZUmLs09j57T3lzo2zCI9o49nu72x04rASVlKMmy9HDKznEUhqi9yUdFP1QQsA5dpNImiRXdhmwCfAa6KmooEwfxrxHEY56fqr7GZEPm9ClwzH7z9sBEOCJ3xZygL/rFzH1Lq3UuRafEdvyJeT/U6dNNro2iROTEl2DotKfVlq0jP7K/GUlsnajv0aWBwsgasKLAOlWZRgFe3ALWe8PwAg)

[My noncompetive solution](https://tio.run/##hVZda1sxDH33r7gtgTbQoO7jJYS87n/oQMtCYS25dGOU7q9nsy3Zknxvlz60jWV9HB0dGTx/v1z419O0@zbRtPs5zUeabtJbejluPqfzcfMlzcfN1/T4fL49Hff7/WG3Ox22b@n0eDtf/XnZvm3uj5v76@n3w3x9wPmBn97T/Irbl7vz3bxN79nw6rQVqx/P1/@@@pRuLhcCAWw@BC4/SJT/zcf9k4/r70SkF7h@w@VG/rtdySb5LB9DfMqxXOUSrByWv7n4UAtK4qG7NGnWyyhXQpbeKmdWfRTDEqdcg69Os0ItxQUurqAXzc0eCrVWcZ8R8slwRazFgpTrMDaJqz/BL5FPyPuFQlnDt1ZYq9rRGCyDTAs@i0cMCZocBQ/msQUGF0HMJt@v5/9aiA4kC18qBo6JzL7yCuVAPWtJAqUhl6M0R6o7EHrTx8skjtWs9ohcGzXFhoKhVOsYWgSs4NjrdWCH44oVhQ6z9qi7lzGXLvMCNkYMan0yo74b1AnqWUpCYKGwThzlbCwRTWX5AAvDIFRpoRGMJFQbrYYmCv41xcJyjmhqe6WBoTrPdOEkFoTDCM4gHXpZWRRSB0xzBo6TFmVErMPeMrEyvCBsIiciEQFL8tonOqzA8GDXIBfqSLZRAqyMsE2dw7ZJhBU2ozUmaF@QKi2uEgwrRggbCGtBeRSTriLtlNxKZEWNjY0PQ6rNMGnGNQg7phz1uLatK@UH9Vb4ZMu0zDHWrkyKRx477XRrdlxF0qyocX2EA4@6/ItokNt@Os3CwKJX5GDtyPU92vcdtQdFAxZLTIYC5fgbSSip1ttDITA7SIkW2sB9DwwIYWkszErAf437yFr2AbTWSaXEwtsJbvga4H4mG9MLHG5MyO2REBbazWBAaI8n3eTk0F94d/mIHKe1w2iq@GDq@wDoMgJjeel3UUbfa@vu5fXhlpd/kg1KYd4L41IQQsE8CKv4mzfKIGhrL0fzwnJDS03Xkf4C)

```
///: no
/a//: yes
/ab/bba/aab: yes
/ab/bba/aaab: yes
/ab/bba/aabb: no
```

## Meta

- Were similar things ever done before?
- I am not even sure if this problem is solvable.
- Just thought there are answers if I clarify maximum length of input.
- Should I change the problem's genre to [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)? Would making a maximum length of the program be boring?

Comment: `///` is turing-complete, so this is not possible

Comment: Should we simplify it more?

Answer (score 4):

## [Gelatin integer metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224704/gelatin-integer-metagolf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Drawing the Stack Overflow logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224852/drawing-the-stack-overflow-logo)

Comment: I don't think restricting the language is a good idea. Move languages promotes diversity among submissions. However, I'm still new to the site so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Like Ender said, language-specific challenges are strongly discouraged - here, it doesn't add anything, so removing the restriction would improve the challenge by allowing a wider variety of approaches and solutions.

Comment: Also, seeing as to how this is a [tag:ascii-art] challenge, you will need to either provide the exact text that needs to be outputted or a formal specification of what is considered valid output and what isn't - for example, could I just submit `.` and claim it's a very zoomed out logo? These will need to be clarified. Overall, I like the idea though.

Comment: I think if you require the output to be the exact example you gave it would make it much easier to determine which answers are valid.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It's the best I got, but I'll make it official.

Comment: This challenge looks pretty good now, so I've upvoted, although I'd still recommend waiting a day or two just in case anyone else has feedback on the formatting or finds something unclear.

Comment: A tip for future challenges: *Anyone* (not just you) reading the challenge and an answer should be able to decide (*without disagreement*) if the answer is valid or not. "Resembles a logo" is *very* subjective in this sense, and phrases like "as close as" should be avoided too.

Comment: @Bubbler Is this better?

Comment: Yeah, it's better. A question: would you allow printing trailing spaces at the end of each line, or printing a trailing newline at the end? (These are commonly allowed because they don't impact the ascii art shown and they're hard to avoid in multiple languages)

Comment: @Bubbler I added a list of questions that are asked in the comments. Can I add the same if I posted this on main?

Comment: I'd recommend to edit the challenge text directly to include any clarifications.

Comment: @Bubbler It will do and I'm hoping that when this gets published, I gain enough reputation just to talk in chat.

Comment: Tags-wise: [kolmogorov-complexity]. I'd suggest just removing the 2 paragraphs beneath the output, as they just make it more confusing. A simple "output this exact text, with an optional trailing newline. Lines may have optional trailing spaces. Shortest code wins" is enough (plus the output itself)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 4):

Comment: It'd be nice to link the ITTM paper. Also, showing an example ITTM and explaining its halting time (like your ⍵×⍵ 2-state ITTM) would be helpful.

Comment: @user41805 I'm currently working on an explanation for my 2-state ITTM champion.  But the animations are a bit time consuming.  I meant to link some ITTM papers, so I will add those links when I finish the edit I am working on.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36747/45613 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable (This doesn't seem to be a duplicate)

Answer (score 4):

## Reveal by Halves (in need of a better name)

[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence)

Inspired by this: http://nolandc.com/smalljs/mouse_reveal/ [(source)](https://github.com/NolanDC/smalljs/tree/master/mouse_reveal).

A valid answer:

- Takes a number
  \$w\$ and (assumed non-negative) integer \$x\$.
- Outputs an integer list with a length of \$2^w\$, initially filled with zeroes.
- For each number \$n\$ from \$0\$ to \$w-1\$ (inclusive), divide the list into sub-lists of size \$2^n\$, then increment all of the values in the sub-list that contains the index \$x\$.

### Examples

(with coordinates from left, 0 indexed, but your answer may have change these)

```
w=3, x=1
23110000

w=2, x=2
0021

w=3, x=5
00002311

w=4, x=4
1111432200000000

w=2, x=100
Do not need to handle (can do anything) because x is out of bounds
```

---

### Meta questions

- Are these tags fitting?
- Would this be better in one dimension? (like \$3, 2\$ returns `11320000`) **Edit**: I've changed it to one dimension but I can revert if it makes it less interesting.
- Should \$w\$ or \$2^w\$ be the input?
- Is this a duplicate?

Comment: My opinions on some meta questions. 1) I think one dimension would be better, the core of the challenge remains the same but the challenge itself becomes more "pure" which, in my opinion, is a good thing. 2) I'm a fan of flexible I/O, so if it were up to me I'd let people choose if they want \$w\$, \$2^w\$ or both as input. If you don't like this, both options are honestly fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Fastest untyped lambda calculus evaluator [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) [lambda-calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

### Challenge

What it says on the tin. Mainly because googling "fastest untyped lambda calculus" gives almost zero meaningful results.

Each submission is expected to take a lambda term from STDIN and print its normal form to STDOUT. The lambda term is represented using de Bruijn indexes, and we will use prefix notation for this challenge. Since a de Bruijn index may have multiple digits, each token will be separated by a single space. The input will have no surrounding whitespace, but you may output any amount of whitespace before and after the formatted lambda term.

```
LambdaChar = "\"             // single backslash
DeBruijnIndex = [1-9][0-9]*  // a positive integer
ApplyChar = "@"
Term = DeBruijnIndex | LambdaChar " " Term | ApplyChar " " Term " " Term
```

For example, `\ \ @ 1 @ 2 1` represents `lambda x. lambda y. y (x y)`.

The evaluation semantics to implement is normal order beta-reduction (no eta-reduction).

The test cases will be hand-crafted so that it takes significantly more time to evaluate the expression than to parse the input and format the output. Also, they will involve various kinds of Church- and Scott-encoded terms, so optimizing for any specifically encoded data (hopefully) has less effect than optimizing for general improvement. It is guaranteed that the test cases have a normal form and do not contain free variables.

Good starting points include [this PEPM '17 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312013355_Compiling_untyped_lambda_calculus_to_lower-level_code_by_game_semantics_and_partial_evaluation_invited_paper) and [my Haskell implementation](https://github.com/Bubbler-4/StepULC) which was modified from the paper's algorithm to actually return the normal form. Other notable keywords: graph reduction, supercombinators, G-machine, TIGRE, STG (spineless tagless G-machine). Note that, if your submission has separate compilation and execution phases, both phases count towards the total execution time (which may negatively impact your score).

The submissions will be scored within WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) on my Windows 10 PC, which has Intel Core i7-6700 CPU (3.40GHz) and 8GB of RAM. The score is the sum of the timings measured for all the test cases. Lowest score wins.

---

### Meta

- Todo: write example and actual test cases.
- Should I include a description about how the "normal order beta reduction" works for de Bruijn indexes?

Comment: are you planning to actually test with >9 levels of lambda nesting?

Comment: @ngn Depends on what I come up with.

Answer (score 4):

## [Demonstrate some advanced abstract algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229765/66833)

Comment: I think we should be able to define the types and values of S, rather than necessarily using integers. In that case, `-` and `+` would not (necessarily) be actual arithmetic negation and addition, so maybe they would have to be renamed to use other symbols (or just use function syntax `f(a,b)`?)

Comment: And do all 9 functions have to operate on the same set S? I think it could be more interesting if they didn't have to, but it might result in cheating/loopholes. Also, what does "uniquely exhibits" mean exactly? Demonstrates **exactly** one of the 9 properties?

Comment: In fact, I think people will just submit "addition, addition, multiplication, subtraction" for the first 4 at least, and I suspect they will almost always be the shortest option in most languages so it might not be very interesting as it is

Comment: Writing one program is hard enough. Writing 9 seems like a lot to ask. I think you could make a stripped down challenge using just commutativity and associativity. I barely known any abstract algebra. I think these varieties are called magmas?

Comment: Is this even possible with the surjectivity condition? You should provide an example of each program.

Comment: @qwr I don't have examples for each program, and even if I did, I wouldn't include them as that would just lead to people porting them into their own languages. Yes, I believe magma is the [correct term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) for \$*\$ here. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd be surprised if it isn't. I've allowed for an answer to be a proof of impossibility however, on that off-chance.

Comment: Well it's more than a magma since you added more two more operators right

Comment: @qwr No, I believe a magma is just a pair, the binary operator and the set its closed on, no matter the additional operators defined on that set

Comment: This is a really cool problem. It *is* hard so I wouldn't be again having a separate "easy" version with just the main three: commutative/associative/distributive. Uniquely exhibiting those is already a nontrivial and neat challenge. I don't know if others would vote a dupe, but I'd def be in favor of having both. As is, I don't think the harder version will have a lot activity. But I do think an easier one would!

Comment: @AviFS I do actually have an [easier version](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22413/66833) Sandboxed, where I think they're clearly separate enough to not be dupes.

Answer (score 4):

## [I'm Lazy*: Top-left align my text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226755/im-lazy-top-left-align-my-text)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

posted

Comment: Definitely not too trivial for code golf

Comment: I think squash up could be its own challenge which has room for simplification. My thoughts being using a transposed grid of strings, which I guess can work for this challenge too

Answer (score 4):

## [Minimal distinct character quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230024/minimal-distinct-character-quine/230025#230025)

Comment: This seems well specificed

Comment: distinct means different?

Comment: @math Yes (filler)

Answer (score 4):

## [Full name quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230620/full-name-quine)

Comment: Nice question but seems hard

Comment: i assume custom SBCS languages will have to output the full names of their characters when represented in unicode? Or should they output the name of the visual representation?

Comment: Full names represented in unicode.

Answer (score 4):

## [`r` my Vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231148/r-flag-my-vyxal)

Comment: Needs more test-cases. Also, in the explanation you use spaces as though they're ignored, but that isn't mentioned in the description of the task itself. I'd suggest just saying that "all other characters" will be limited to ASCII letters only, for example?.

Comment: @pxeger In Vyxal, spaces are NOPs used to seperate stuff. In the subset I'm using, spaces are a function like everything else. I'll make that clearer, and add more testcases.

Comment: But I'm suggesting limiting the definition of what are functions to ASCII letters only to provide more golfing opportunities without having to handle edge cases that might occur because of spaces

Comment: @pxeger Ok.  (filler)

Comment: It says that we can assume there will always be two values to pop, but one of the testcases is simply “1”. Is that something that we will have to account for?

Comment: @AaronMiller What I meant is, wherever there's a function, there will be two. I'll add that.

Answer (score 4):

## Converting Pinyin to Zhuyin or vice versa

### Challenge

Pinyin and Zhuyin are systems that are used to help people pronounce characters in Mandarin Chinese. Write a function/program that converts Pinyin to Zhuyin or vice versa (clarify which one you are doing) according to the tables below. You are not required to deal with tones or incorrect inputs (including edge cases such as ḿ(呣), ǹg(嗯), and ê̄(诶/誒)).

#### Pinyin to Zhuyin

| Pinyin | Zhuyin |
| --- | --- |
| b | ㄅ |
| p | ㄆ |
| m | ㄇ |
| f | ㄈ |
| d | ㄉ |
| t | ㄊ |
| n (at the beginning) | ㄋ |
| l | ㄌ |
| g (at the beginning) | ㄍ |
| k | ㄎ |
| h (at the beginning) | ㄏ |
| j | ㄐ |
| q | ㄑ |
| x | ㄒ |
| zh (except in zhi) zhi | ㄓ |
| ch (except in chi) chi | ㄔ |
| sh (except in shi) shi | ㄕ |
| r (at the beginning) ri | ㄖ |
| z (except in zh, zi) zi | ㄗ |
| c (except in ch, ci) ci | ㄘ |
| s (except in sh, si) si | ㄙ |
| a (at the end) | ㄚ |
| o (except in ao, ou, ong) | ㄛ |
| e (except in ei, en, eng, er, ie, ue, üe, ye) | ㄜ |
| e (only in ie, ue, üe, ye) | ㄝ |
| i (except in ai, ei, ui, iu, iong, yi, zhi, chi, shi, ri, zi, ci, si) y (except in yong, yi) yi | ㄧ |
| u (except in ou, iu, wu, ue and except after j, q, x, y) w (except in wu) wu o (only in ong except in iong, yong) | ㄨ |
| u (right after j, q, x) ü yu io yo (only in yong) | ㄩ |
| ai | ㄞ |
| ei i (only in ui) | ㄟ |
| ao | ㄠ |
| ou u (only in iu) | ㄡ |
| an (except in ang) | ㄢ |
| ang | ㄤ |
| en (except in eng) n (only in in, un except in ing) | ㄣ |
| eng ng (only in ing, ong) | ㄥ |
| er | ㄦ |

#### Zhuyin to Pinyin

| Zhuyin | Pinyin |
| --- | --- |
| ㄅ | b |
| ㄆ | p |
| ㄇ | m |
| ㄈ | f |
| ㄉ | d |
| ㄊ | t |
| ㄋ | n |
| ㄌ | l |
| ㄍ | g |
| ㄎ | k |
| ㄏ | h |
| ㄐ | j |
| ㄑ | q |
| ㄒ | x |
| ㄓ (by itself) | zhi |
| ㄓ (not by itself) | zh |
| ㄔ (by itself) | chi |
| ㄔ (not by itself) | ch |
| ㄕ (by itself) | shi |
| ㄕ (not by itself) | sh |
| ㄖ (by itself) | ri |
| ㄖ (not by itself) | r |
| ㄗ (by itself) | zi |
| ㄗ (not by itself) | z |
| ㄘ (by itself) | ci |
| ㄘ (not by itself) | c |
| ㄙ (by itself) | si |
| ㄙ (not by itself) | s |
| ㄚ | a |
| ㄛ | o |
| ㄜ | e |
| ㄝ | e |
| ㄧ (at the beginning, not by itself, and not before ㄣ, ㄥ) | y |
| ㄧ (after ㄐ, ㄑ, ㄒ) | i |
| ㄧ (by itself or before ㄣ, ㄥ and at the beginning) | yi |
| ㄨ (not at the beginning) | u |
| ㄨ (at the beginning except by itself) | w |
| ㄨ (by itself) | wu |
| ㄨ (before ㄥ and not at the beginning) | o |
| ㄩ (after ㄐ, ㄑ, ㄒ) | u |
| ㄩ (after ㄋ, ㄌ) | ü |
| ㄩ (by itself or before ㄝ, ㄢ, ㄣ and at the beginning) | yu |
| ㄩ (not at the beginning and before ㄥ) | io |
| ㄩ (at the beginning and before ㄥ) | yo |
| ㄞ | ai |
| ㄟ (not after ㄨ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | ei |
| ㄟ (after ㄨ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | i |
| ㄠ | ao |
| ㄡ (not after ㄧ unless ㄧ is at the beginning) | ou |
| ㄡ (after ㄧ unless ㄧ is at the beginning) | u |
| ㄢ | an |
| ㄤ | ang |
| ㄣ (not after ㄧ, ㄨ, ㄩ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | en |
| ㄣ (after ㄧ, ㄨ, ㄩ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | n |
| ㄥ (not after ㄧ, ㄨ, ㄩ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | eng |
| ㄥ (after ㄧ, ㄨ, ㄩ unless ㄨ is at the beginning) | ng |
| ㄦ | er |

This is code-golf, so the answer with the least bytes wins.

### Test Cases

| Pinyin | Zhuyin |
| --- | --- |
| chuang | ㄔㄨㄤ |
| xue | ㄒㄩㄝ |
| diu | ㄉㄧㄡ |
| juan | ㄐㄩㄢ |
| ri | ㄖ |
| song | ㄙㄨㄥ |
| lü | ㄌㄩ |
| qiong | ㄑㄩㄥ |
| zhen | ㄓㄣ |
| huo | ㄏㄨㄛ |
| ying | ㄧㄥ |

[Additional test cases and information](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Ensw/chinese/pinyin.htm)

Comment: Am I required to support single characters or a word / sentence? Also, there are some edge cases as I know, for example, ḿ(呣), ǹg(嗯), ê̄(诶/誒). Would these be excluded from testcases? May I assume no erhua (儿化/兒化) would be applied?

Comment: There are far more rules than testcases. I would suggest to add more testcases as many rules are not ever touched by any testcases here.

Comment: @tsh Single characters. The edge cases would not be required to check for as inputs. No erhua. I will try to add some more testcases to cover the other rules.

Comment: Suggest a whole list, it's likely just 300+ possible inputs

Comment: The number of rules makes this an intimidating task to write and golf. Consider limited to a simpler subset of rules or situations.

Comment: @xnor It's not actually as many rules as it looks like. A simple regex can be used for most of them.

Comment: This is probably a lot harder to reason about for people not already familiar with mandarin and pinyin.

Answer (score 4):

### Play RPS with 3 bits of memory

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[restricted-memory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-memory)

*This is a rough draft for now, the specifics, presentation and title will probably be adjusted*

In this game you will be building bots to play rock paper scissors against each other.  Of course rock paper scissors is not a very interesting game, just pick one of the three randomly. Can't get better than that?

The first thing here is that, we will play a slight variation on the game which introduces a small amount of strategy.

But more importantly in this version we will be designing *very* simple bots.  Your bot will not be able to pick things randomly, nor will it be able to simulate complex strategies, because your bots will have 3 bits of working memory.

### The game

Before we get into exactly how the bots will be made and what exactly it means to have only 3 bits of memory lets cover the game.

For each pair of bots we will play 48 rounds of RPS.  In each round both bots will select a choice of Rock, Paper or Scissors.  Rock beats scissors, paper beats rock and Scissors beats paper, if the two chose the same move they tie.

When you win you will receive points based on your play.  If you win with scissors you get 1 point, if you win with paper you get 3 points, and if you win with rock you get 6 points.  If you tie or lose you get 0 points.

Each bot will play every other bot and the bots will be scored on the number of points gained in total.

### The bots

Your bot will have 3 bits of working memory, that means at any given time it will have stored a number between 0 and 7.  To decide what to play it will know two things

1. What it has in memory
2. The last move it's opponent made

Given those it should spit out

1. What move it wants to make
2. 3-bits to write into memory

This is so simple you don't actually need to write "code" to represent your bot. Your bot is really just a \$8\times 3\$ lookup table, plus a single move which it will make as it's first move. (We can assume that the starting memory is `0` without loss of generality)

And in fact you will submit your bots in this format as it makes it easy to verify your bot works and doesn't cheat.

---

### Sandbox

I like this challenge because it is

1. Completely deterministic who wins, to the point where you can, for small bot pool work out with pen and paper the scores.
2. It is basically language agnostic.  No need to bother with JS.
3. There's basically no way to cheat.  It's going to be really hard to exploit a vulnerability in the handler when you can't run arbitrary code.

I am a little concerned though that there might not be a whole lot to do?  I'm not sure how much better one bot really can be than others.  Obviously you can always take 1 bot and design a bot which plays perfectly against it.  But I'm not totally sure how much a carefully arranged bot is going to do better than ones that are just a pile of random connections.

Turning the memory size up could improve this but the larger you make it the more complex each bot gets, and I think the fun is really in being able to hand tune your bot.

However I don't know what I can do to find out other than just post this.

Comment: Seems bruteforceable

Comment: This is a unique challenge, and I think you could post it. If it doesn't work out, then we'll all know not to do it again (or an improved version could be posted later). If it does work, CGCC'll have a new kind of challenge, which would be great.

Comment: @pxeger There are 1333735776850284124449081472843776 machines possible.  Brute forcing that would probably mean playing every machine against every other machine.  It may be *solvable*, but I don't think it is feasible to brute force it.

Comment: I'd prefer to have rigid I/O (fixed I/O method and format) for KotH purposes. Or you could just say "write down the 8x3+1 possible outputs in a specific format". The barrier to post *some* bot looks pretty low, so I'd expect a large number of answers in the worst(?) case which would require some kind of automated controller.

Comment: @WheatWitch ah, I misread the challenge

Comment: @bubbler oh I absolutely will write a controller once the rules are nailed down a bit. Just because you can score this by hand does not mean it would not be very tedious

Answer (score 4):

## [Remove submatrices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236884/100664)

Answer (score 4):

## [Converge to a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238607/converge-to-a-number)

Answer (score 4):

## [Schrödinger's cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240225/98630)

Comment: This is probably good to post now, and it looks like a good challenge!

Answer (score 4):

## [Incrementally Increment Identical Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240421/110034)

Comment: Total rewording suggestion for everything up until before "To demonstrate": *Given a non-empty non-descending list of any integers, increment each number by how many identical elements occur to its left.*

Comment: @Adám For what it's worth, I find that less understandable than the current description. It's probably a difference of APL mindset vs. Python mindset.

Answer (score 4):

## [Egyptian fraction representations of 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241222)

Answer (score 4):

## [Remove odd indices and double the even indices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241267)

Comment: The test cases are now consistent with the example explanation, but not with the "remove odd, double even" description. You could fix this by either changing this to "remove even, double odd", or switching to 0-indexing

Answer (score 4):

## [Score a Scrabble Play](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241889/score-a-scrabble-play)

Comment: I think removing the letter points mapping from the challenge as you suggest is a good idea. Otherwise a lot of the byte count will be taken up just in storing the map, with less of the answer being the interesting part, which is the scoring algorithm. Honestly it might even be worth assuming all letters score `1`, because the interesting computational problem is really just detecting what the words formed in the grid are.

Comment: @pxeger I think I would like to keep the specific point values, so that the challenge still involves the words themselves somehow. Otherwise it would suffice just to find the distances between relevant tiles and certain empty squares as well as losing some (important, in my opinion) flavor.

Comment: That's a good point; I hadn't considered that the letters themselves would no longer matter in that case. I'd still recommend going for the version with points mapping as input.

Comment: Where do we get the word dictionary?

Comment: @GingerIndustries There is no need for a word dictionary. As I wrote in my post, answers do not need to consider the legality of the play.

Answer (score 4):

[Find the index of the matching parentheses for each character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242263/find-the-index-of-the-matching-parentheses-for-each-character)

Comment: please check if i have explained properly as some may not understand

Answer (score 4):

## [Find my Māori pronouns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242702/find-my-m%c4%81ori-pronouns)

Answer (score 4):

## Print 2^n graph in ASCII

Your challenge is to output this infinite graph:

```
o
o
oo
oo
oo
oo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
oooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
...
```

with the xth line having floor(log_2(x)) `o`s (or other characters). Tag: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity.

Comment: wow this looks interesting tbh, is there supposed to be a ```\n``` at the start of the sequence?

Comment: @DialFrost Yeah, because floor(log_2(1)) = 0.

Comment: nice, but is there a reason you chose `o`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Is it a tower permutation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243173/is-it-a-tower-permutation)

Comment: Maybe add a link to your previous tower challenge?

Comment: @pxeger I'll add a comment once I post this

Answer (score 4):

## Gambling with an Alien

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Find the challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/243604/111187)!

Comment: Welcome to code golf and thanks for using Sandbox! Are wee allowed to implement less restrictive output requirement, i.e. using our default [tag:decision-problem] rules ([tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info))? - I suggest it over using two fixed strings (that not all languages can handle).

Comment: @pajonk That seems like a good change! I'll implement it.

Answer (score 4):

[Crate art stacking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243630/crate-art-stacking)

Comment: Is trailing whitespace allowed?

Comment: This one is much better than the Stack Em one.

Comment: @pajonk do you think its better to allow or not allow?

Comment: I think I usually see allowing trailing whitespace in such challenges. Also, I'm always on the side of loosening I/O requirements.

Answer (score 4):

## [Repeat List Until Longer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/243958/107299)

Comment: I think the output for the last example should be `[2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5]`?

Comment: Ah yes, that was my muscle memory being a little off. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of second list as input take only its length.

Comment: This problem is component of a solution for another problem. I prefer it like this.

Answer (score 4):

## Can you decrypt me?

### Cops

Cops, post obfuscated code that hides a number \$n\$ inside its code. If \$n\$ chars are changed, the program outputs \$n\$. Otherwise, it outputs a different number. Both programs may not error, and there can be multiple solutions.

### Robbers

Find any combination of chars to change and what they should change into. You may not crack a cop's answer with anything of the form `loop through all possible changes, find one that works`.

### Example

```python
print(2)
```

N is 1.

---

Robbers' post:

```python
print(1)
```

### Scoring

Cops, the user with the most uncracked posts wins.
Robbers, the user with the most cracks wins.

Comment: How could you stop robbers writes a code that try to apply cops code on every possible inputs until find out one matching output?

Comment: @tsh uh, can you clarify?

Comment: Does this mean robber just need to write a program that `for (i in AllPossibleInputs) if (CopsCode(i) == CopsOutput) return i`?

Comment: @tsh, is it possible to enforce "don't do that?"

Comment: This is a good format for a CnR, but you need to specify scoring criteria. For the cops, "shortest code" ([tag:code-golf]) is probably good enough. For robbers, something like "most cracked answer". You should probably add a rule to allow uncracked cops' answers to become "safe" after a certain amount of time (probably around 1-2 weeks)

Comment: @pxeger does it need more clarifying and details? (other then scoring criteria)

Comment: No, if you add those things, it will be ok

Answer (score 4):

## [The Missing Match](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245315/the-missing-match)

Comment: The task becomes clear by the end but I think some reorganisation of the text would help. In the second sentence you say 'The braces are all balanced', but further down we find out that this isn't actually true: 'inside the string there is a single unbalanced brace'. I'd suggest these two bits of information should be closer together.

Comment: @Dingus thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer; would you care to take a look?

Comment: Looks good to me, but one other thing - I'd suggest *brackets* is a more appropriate word than *braces* here.

Comment: @Dingus sure, thanks! Do you suggest I post it anytime soon or wait another day or so?

Comment: The general recommendation is to leave it in the Sandbox a few days at least, just to maximise the number of eyes that see it before it goes on main.

Answer (score 4):

## What does the text talk about?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [machine-learning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) *note that the machine-learning tag will be new*

**META: this is far from being done. I also understand that this challenge depends heavily on manual opinion about the "type" of a piece of text. Hence, if you take issue with that, I would appreciate your giving a comment that suggests ways to fix that issue, rather than an unjustified downvote related to that issue.**

**Additionally, this might be a duplicate. I would appreciate your pointing this out *before* I compile the list of texts, if possible. However, if you identify a duplicate after I start compiling the list of texts, that is also fine.**

Some parts use the future tense to talk about what I *will* do. Obviously I will have done them by the time I post the challenge.

The sections in *italic* could be taken as being ambiguous.

The links to the training, validation and test sets are not available yet. And of course, I don't yet have labels on my side.

---

This is a project that I once attempted to do, having learned machine learning. I run a forum app, and I was thinking of incorporating my new machine learning knowledge into that app by creating a model that could detect topics related to a given topic. After having worked on it for a few days, I hadn't made much progress, so I abandoned it. I hereby challenge you to make a similar model, ideally with machine learning, but that is not required. Your model will classify the topic of a piece of text. Such a model could then be used to find text related to a given piece of text by finding texts with a similar topic. You can choose to write your model without machine learning.

This is thus essentially a machine learning challenge. (or ideally, it will be. You may choose to write your solution without machine learning, but I am mainly looking forward to seeing machine learning solutions.) I will provide a large set of "articles", divided into a training set, a validation set, and a test set, with a 60-30-10 split. I expect there to be about 500 articles in all.

The articles in the training and validation sets are labeled with their topics: for instance, history, geography, mathematics, programming, etc. The test set, importantly, **does not have public-facing labels**, but I have labels on my side.

The training set is available [here](https://www.example.com).

The validation set is available [here](https://www.example.com).

The test set is available [here](https://www.example.com).

### Challenge

Write a classifier that attempts to classify the topic of a piece of text. The possible topics are:

(coming soon)

You can choose any of (coming soon) distinct values to represent the topic.

It should be able to produce an output that is one, and only one, of the chosen distinct values given any input string.

You have access to the train set to teach your classifier to recognize the topics (if you are using machine learning). The validation set can be used to compare different approaches.

Your submission will be scored based on how well it does on the test set. I will write the test set articles in such a way that they are not ambiguous (`500 years ago, a mathematician discovered a method to calculate integrals` is ambiguous as the sentence could be about mathematics or history, but `Learn about the way people lived 1000 years ago` is only about history). Your score is the number of articles it can correctly classify out of the test set. The higher the number of articles your submission can correctly classify, the better the score is. Thus the winner of this challenge is the submission that classifies the most articles correctly.

**Importantly, this is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).** I expect this to be a challenge that demands significant time and effort to produce a solution that scores highly, so you may post a link to a GitHub repository hosting the solution if required.

You are encouraged to either provide a way to easily run your solution, or provide the list of outputs that your code produces when given the test set articles. Even better, you could post a Jupyter notebook (if you are answering with a supported language) containing your solution, complete with test set outputs.

**Important: please do not post a solution that is optimized only for the test set. It should work *reasonably well* in general.**

Just so that you can get an idea of the topics:

```
Article: The dinosaurs went extinct 66 million years ago due to an asteroid impact.
Topic: history

Article: Time complexity is a measure of the complexity of an algorithm. For instance, the operation of adding two integers is usually taken to have a complexity of O(1). The operation of summing a list given as input has a complexity of O(n) where n is the size of the input.
Topic: programming

Article: Partial derivatives are derivatives taken with respect to one variable.
Topic: mathematics

Article: Planes are for going on holiday, especially island getaways.
Topic: holiday

Article: Carrot Cake Potato Mushroom
Topic: food
```

Comment: [joke] mathematica probably has a builtin for this

Answer (score 4):

## [Haplololololololology!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247165/haplololololololology)

Comment: Suggested test case: `aaaabaaaab` -> `aaaab`, as a simple example of matching the longest sequences not producing the shortest result (which would be `abab`)

Comment: Thanks, added...

Comment: What about something like `filed edit`?

Comment: It would yield `filedit` - or were you suggesting I add it to the test cases?

Comment: Isn't mississippi -> miss**i**ppi?

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Edited down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space.

Answer (score 4):

## [Matrix Meets ASCII Art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247109/matrix-meets-ascii-art#247109)

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to contain at least one `1`? How should we handle all-`0` rows? (will it ever be a case?) Are the `1`s going to be always neighbours? I suggest adding some more examples/test-cases.

Answer (score 4):

## [Straighten my corners... diagonally](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247862/straighten-my-corners-diagonally)

Comment: This is OEIS [A060736](https://oeis.org/A060736). [Sample Python copied from OEIS.](https://tio.run/##Hcw7DgIxDEXRnlW4dBzMkAkIhBT2MhI/p3BGkRtWHzwUrzlPuuvXPk3zGK/WQUEU@qLvJ6Z9PobbDsCKqCHilZQvgehw5hSmaQ7@SVE2Qot/cagFjSxm32kjVse1bwW5lwqLPkBIuMbUOlYvEc1Rwhg/)

Comment: Cheesy title suggestion: straighten my corners... diagonally

Comment: @chunes That sounds great, thanks!

Comment: Also, you probably realize this, but the question doesn't currently have a score criterion.

Comment: @chunes Nice catch, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Make the list Fibonacci-like](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248281/108879)

Answer (score 4):

## The Magic Money Machine

*This KOTH is based on a game of Tom Scott's series [Money](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJSI7QTAt_o), so make sure to check out his video*

---

## Challenge

There are three rounds per game. Each bot will get `100$`.
They'll have to decide how much money they'll keep for themselves, and how much they're going to put in the Magic Money Machine.
The money in the Machine will get a `20%` boost in the first round, a `50%` boost in the second round, and a `100%` boost in the third round.
Each bot will equally get the money left in the Machine.

#### Example:

- Bot `A` decides to put `60$` in the Money Machine and keep `40$` for themselves
- Bot `B` decides to put `30$` in the Money Machine and keep `70$` for themselves
- In total there are `90$` in the Money Machine, so with a boost of eg. `20%` that's `108$`, so each bot will get an additional `54$`
- Bot `A` has `94$` in the end
- Bot `B` has `124$` in the end

**You have to try to get as much money as possible.**

### Rules:

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- No interaction with the controller other than by returning values.
- No interaction with other bots

### API Template

```python
def plan(round_num, others_money):
    # Tell the other bots how much money you're going to put in the Machine
    # You are allowed to lie
    return money_insert_pub

def main(round_num, others_money, others_plan):
    # Do stuff here
    return money_insert
```

- `round_num`: an integer ranging from 1 to 3, it depicts the current round
- `others_money`: a list of 0, 1, or 2 tuples. Each tuple will contain the `money_kept` var of the other bots of the last rounds (yours incl.).
- `money_insert_pub`: the `money_insert` value you're telling others
- `money_insert`: an integer between 0 to 100, the amount of money you put in the Magic Money Machine
- `others_plan`: the `money_insert_pub` value of the other bots (yours incl.)

**Controller code is on [Github](https://github.com/SE-Nitro/Magic-Money-Machine)**

### Example bots

#### Beep Boopy Random

```python
import random
def plan(round_num, others_money):
    global money_insert
    money_insert = random.randint(0, 100)
    return money_insert

def main(round_num, others_money, others_plans):
    return money_insert
```

#### Random copycat

```python
import random
def plan(round_num, others_money):
    return 100

def main(round_num, others_money, others_plan):
    if round_num == 1:
        money_insert = random.randint(0, 100)
    else:
        money_insert = (
            random.choice(others_money[-1]) if others_money else random.randint(0, 100)
        )
    return money_insert
```

## Meta

- This is my first (well sort of) KOTH, is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Is the controller function written yet? You might want to link to it on Github.

Comment: @Steffan [not yet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61321754#61321754) :P

Comment: but now I'm done

Comment: It looks like the bot that never donates will always win because "Each bot will equally get the money left in the Machine?" Am I missing something?

Comment: @WezloOvOo damn maybe one sec

Answer (score 4):

## [Iteratively delete a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248602/iteratively-delete-a-list/248604#248604)

Answer (score 4):

## [Give f and g that sometimes commute](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248537/give-f-and-g-that-sometimes-commute)

Comment: @WheatWizard, how's this?

Comment: Seems good.  A little odd that when anonymous functions are only allowed for the separate submissions, but understandable.

Comment: What restrictions are there on the codomains of the functions? E.g. are \$f(x)=\frac32 x\$, \$f(x)=i^x\$, \$f(x)=\frac1{x^2}\$ valid?

Comment: @att by "over the integers", i mean that the domain and codomain are integers. i'll clarify.

Comment: You've specified these functions to act on all integers, but it may be annoying for answers to handle negative numbers and/or zero. Is there a reason you don't restrict the input to positive integers, or allow answers to decide which of \$ \{ \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z^+, \mathbb Z^* \} \$ they handle?

Comment: @pxeger no reason! i think the extra flexibility is okay. i'll edit the question so that people can choose, but i think it's still reasonable to require the domain and codomain to be equal (because these functions should be composed).

Comment: Can I use builtins without explicitly declaring them? for instance, using \$f(x)=\text{abs}(x)\$, 0 bytes? Plus, why do I have to enter `\$` here...?

Comment: @NobodyNeedsNames at minimum you need to submit `abs` (like how other builtin submissions are)

Answer (score 4):

[Universal Unicode Clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248648/56656)

Comment: How does this have to do with [tag:polyglot]?

Comment: @Steffan It's a program which runs on different versions of a library.  So it's a sort of library polyglot.

Comment: If the Unicode handling library has an interface to determine which version of the Unicode database it uses, are we allowed to use that?

Comment: @pxeger I'm not sure if there is really any point in disallowing it since it seems unlikely that it would get you many votes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Extend a matrix in all directions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248796/extend-a-matrix-in-all-directions)

Comment: Why is the second input another array, and not just the dimensions of the output array?

Comment: @pxeger Good point

Answer (score 4):

## [Not-Roman-Numeral Addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249152/not-roman-numeral-addition)

Comment: (from the test cases) How is `110015`, `ICIV`, 94? `IC` is `99` + `IV` which is 4 should be 103. I'd suggest removing that test case though, because `ICIV` is not technically a valid roman numeral.

Comment: The second-to-last test case is also wrong apparently: the second number is `MMCCCXL` which is `2340`, not `2345`, so the result is `3574`

Comment: @Steffan fixed and fixed

Comment: this is basically roman numeral addition right? with translating before and after to numeric symbols

Answer (score 4):

## [ro1000an nu1000era50 en100o501ng](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249107/ro1000an-nu1000era50-en100o501ng)

Comment: I suggest adding a worked out example - the test cases were still confusing for me after reading the challenge body.

Answer (score 4):

## Word stays a word after taking away a letter

### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249403/word-stays-a-word-after-taking-away-a-letter)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input will contain a solution?

Comment: @pajonk I think it's better to say no, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Next digit of rational number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250066/101306) [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: A good test case might be `1.221122`, which I believe should result in an output of `2`

Comment: Good idea, added it

Comment: Is the decimal separator important to the challenge? I feel like it might be better to just have no decimal separator

Comment: @CommandMaster It isn't really that important, but I wanted the challenge make sense so this is why I kept it there. I expect that for most languages it will just be single replace, tr or something.

Answer (score 4):

## [All Possible Ties in Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249941/all-possible-ties-in-tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 4):

## [Count the cells](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250113/count-the-cells)

Answer (score 4):

## Halve a string

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250213/generate-an-arbitrary-half-of-a-string)

Comment: If this was a decision problem, it would be easier to give test cases (because it would true/false instead of many different possible outputs)

Comment: I guess another possible task is to output the list of all halves of a given string.

Answer (score 4):

## Swap every two elements in the list every possible way

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250419/swap-every-two-elements-in-the-list-every-possible-way)

Comment: Welcome to the Code Golf SE! I have a few questions about your problem:
1) Should the output include the original order? Examples 2 and 3 do, but example 1 doesn't.
2) I might be mistaken, but isn't this equivalent to finding all permutations of the array?

Comment: @Adam
1) The output should include the original order only if the original order can be reached by applying every possible pair swap in some order. For example 1, the only possible swap just swaps two elements, and so only one permutation can be reached. For example 3, there is no possible swap, so the array stays the same, and for example 2, there are a lot of different possible results that happen to include the original order.

2) You are mistaken in that case. It isn't all permutations, it's slightly more complicated than that. It's a little bit of a research problem.

Answer (score 4):

## Rearrange to a palindrome

Given a string, shuffle it so that it becomes a palindrome.

For example, `adadbcc` can be arranged into `dacbcad`, or `dcabacd`, `acdbdca` and more. Any of these (or all) is acceptable, and duplicates are allowed if outputting all. Something like `abc` cannot be shuffled into a palindrome, and you can assume it won't be inputted.

(if it helps) input will only contain lowercase letters.

### Testcases

These show one possible solution.

```
nanas -> nasan
coconutnut -> conuttunoc
apotato -> atopota
manplancanalpanamaaaa -> amanaplanacanalpanama
canadadance -> canadedanac
```

Answer (score 4):

## Use "e" or a suffix?

### Background

In [Māori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81ori_language) (the indigenous language of New Zealand), to make a verb a command the verb is either preceded by "e" for example, "oma" (to run) -> "e oma", or, it's given a passive ending to make it a [passive verb](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/passive-verbs.html) for example "kōrero" (to speak, talk, say, etc) -> "kōrerotia".

Besides some edge cases with [intransitive verbs](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/verbs) and different dialects, the rule is that if the verb has exactly two short vowels or one long vowel (which have macrons over the top of them like "ā") then the verb is preceded with "e" otherwise it is given a suffix.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to determine whether which case a verb fits in to. If it should be preceded by "e" output a truthy value, otherwise output a falsey value.

### Rules

- You can assume that all the input will be lower case.
- You may *not* take input with [combining diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).
- Because there are very few, if any verbs in Māori with only one short vowel, and the fact that what happens in that case depends on dialect, you don't need to handle those cases.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer wins.

### Test cases

```
ako -> true
kai -> true
haere -> false
tū -> true
āwhina -> false
kōrero -> false
huri -> true
```

### Meta

- Thoughts on the combining diacritics rule?
- Are there any other rules that should be added?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Maybe add a test case with a single short vowel? (Or if there are no actual mono-moraic verbs, consider including in the spec that such an input doesn't have to be considered.)

Comment: @UnrelatedString I was thinking about that, I haven't been able to find any verbs with one short vowel, but I just can't be sure that there are none so I'm not really sure what to do about it.

Comment: [Fix your link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040720/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/active-and-passive-verbs)! (It's the second one.)

Comment: @Laurel Ah, thanks. I'll replace it with a new one.

Comment: Tag: [tag:decision-problem]

Comment: You should also probably specify that it has to be *exactly* two short/one long, and the cases are mutually exclusive -- e.g. say "...the verb has **exactly two short vowels or two long vowels, but not both**"

Comment: @Adam true, done.

Answer (score 4):

## Every \$ n \$th repeat [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

Given a list of positive integers, and another integer \$ n \$, output every \$ n \$th instance of each distinct item in the list, starting with the first, in the order they appear in the original list.

For example, with \$ n = 2 \$, we will output the first instance of each item, but not the second, but we will output the third, and so on.

If \$ n = 2 \$ and the list is `4 1 3 2 3 1 6 3 4 1 1`, then:

- `1` occurs four times, so only the first and third will be kept
- `4` occurs twice, and only the first will be kept
- `3` occurs three times; the first and third will be kept
- `2` and `6` only occur once each, so their first and only occurrences will be kept

Therefore, the output is `4 1 3 2 6 3 1`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

todo

## Meta

- [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250213) (\$ n = 2 \$, and more open ended)
- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?

Answer (score 4):

## [IE's Extra Robust Color Parsing®](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250535/ies-extra-robust-color-parsing)

Comment: So `#FFF` (white in today's browsers) became `#0F0F0F` (very dark grey)‽

Comment: When you say output as an "a RGB color", you should clarify whether you mean the text formatted as an RGB color string, or to graphically output the color itself

Comment: @Adám So it would seem, I noticed that as well.

Comment: @thejonymyster right, poor wording on my part. Fixed.

Comment: Could you please add comments to less obvious steps in the worked out examples? (I don't get the `AD0, AC0, 0E0 --> AD, AC, 0E`, as the algorithm says to remove characters always from the front.) Also, I suggest adding some more test-cases (not necessarily worked out, but in a copy-friendly format).

Comment: @pajonk I added some comments, planning to add some test cases later whan I find the time.

Comment: Will IE recognize some special words like `red`, `white`? Or `red` is processed into `#000e0d`?

Comment: @tsh Good point, thanks! IE probably did respect them, but for the challenge, we'll process them. Updated the rules.

Comment: I assume we just have to output the six resulting characters, and the leading `#` in the output is optional?

Comment: Yes, I just used that to mark the results.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cryptic Multiplications](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250745/94346)

Answer (score 4):

## [Anti-divisors of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250883/78410)

Answer (score 4):

## [An algorithm to find even sublime numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251270/78410)

Answer (score 4):

## [Count Futoshiki row solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252340/count-futoshiki-row-solutions)

Answer (score 4):

## [Print 100 digits of π](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265634/print-100-digits-of-%cf%80)

Comment: How can I verify someone's answer is correct or not if they claim it is \pi starts with index 10345292438624234? or even worse Ackermann(10000, 10000)?

Comment: @tsh How can *they* verify it either?

Comment: How about this: all answers must be verifiable through the [Pi API](https://pi.delivery/). Example: https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=1&numberOfDigits=100&radix=10 gives the first 100 digits. Change the "start" query to "intended index + 1" to get different portions of pi. Rationale: the current world record for digits of pi is 10^14 digits and no one has *confirmed* the digits beyond that (even if someone has computed more), so the challenge is unanswerable outside the range anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[Is it an alphadrome?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253088/is-it-an-alphadrome)

Answer (score 4):

## Alternating sublists

Suppose a contiguous sublist that has at least three numbers and alternates between even and odd numbers (or odd and even) is called an alternating sublist. An alternating sublist cannot switch between alternating even and odd numbers to odd to even or vice versa.

Given an input array, find the number of alternating sublists. Zero is considered even, and overlapping is allowed.

For example, in the following input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

There are three sublists of length 3, of which two are alternating `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 4]`. `[3, 4, 6]` is not an alternating as it contains two even numbers in a row.

Also, there is one more alternating sublist with a length of 4 `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The entire string is not alternating, as two even numbers are in a row. Thus, the answer is 3.

### Test cases

```
[2, 3, 4, 5] => 3
[50, 50, 10, 80, 96] => 0
[9, 8, 7, 2] => 3
[2, 2, 2, 2, -555, 0] => 1
[1, 2, 4, 6] => 0
[10, 11, 12] => 1
[98, 33, 11] => 0
```

(some test cases with negative numbers coming soon)

### Scoring

Your score is the number of alternating substrings your program has. For scoring purposes, convert all non-numeric chars to their corresponding ASCII code. The tie-breaker is the shortest code. The winner is the answer with the lowest score.

---

- I think the scoring system may be better with "shortest code wins"
- I also think the sentence "An alternating sublist cannot switch between alternating even and odd numbers to odd to even or vice versa.
  " may be a little confusing, but I can't think of a good alternative.

Comment: The description is unclear to me. 1) Does "substrings" mean "contiguous sublists"? 2) "Find substrings" indicates to me that we should return substrings, but the test case returns an integer. 3) There are more than two contiguous sublists of `[2,3,4,5]` that alternate between odd and even: `[2,3]`, `[3,4]`, `[4,5]`, `[2,3,4]`, `[3,4,5]`, `[2,3,4,5]`. Do you mean "find the maximum number of *non-overlapping* contiguous sublists"?

Comment: @DLosc fixed. better?

Comment: Better, yes. I made a small change to the sentence order that I think makes it even clearer. I do think a step-by-step worked example before the test cases would be helpful--especially since I just realized that both the original wording and the edited wording said the substrings must have length strictly greater than 2, but I managed to misunderstand that as greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: @DLosc Added step-by-step example.

Comment: @DLosc fixed x3

Comment: There should be at least two test cases of length 3, one alternating and one non-alternating. I'd suggest adding one very long test case, too. Is there a maximum length solutions need to handle?

Comment: @DLosc I've added more test cases, though I'm not quite sure what the best way to express "as high as your language supports."

Comment: "Your program should be able to handle input as high as your language supports" seems a bit ambiguous.

Comment: For starters, since we're talking about lists rather than integers, I'd say "long" rather than "high."

Comment: Can't understand, seem be inconsistancy

Comment: @l4m2 please clarify

Comment: Seems by your definition a list with a length of 1 would be alternating

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing "substring" to "contiguous sublist" as suggested by @DLosc -- to me, substring definitely has the connotation of being a slice of a string (list of characters; I want to make sure we're on the same page). Even just "sublist" would be okay, just clarify somewhere that you're talking about the contiguous kind.

Comment: @Jacob ok fixed

Answer (score 4):

## MD5 Hello, World!

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253296/41374)

Comment: Are there interesting ways of getting two files to have the same MD5 hash? I know there are some ways to add arbitrary text to files to give them the same hash, but it seems difficult to engineer the program itself to have the same hashes.

Comment: @97.100.97.109, I’m not sure. It may be interesting to see if someone can come up with a solution that is a bit smarter than including a lot of unused data.

Answer (score 4):

## [Count the shared substrings with 2 programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253441/count-the-shared-substrings-with-2-programs)

Comment: incident, score 0, fermat quote

Answer (score 4):

## [Character Insertion on Letterboards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253667/character-insertion-on-letterboards)

Comment: Can we assume it's a permutation of the string?

Comment: I think the example has a mistake, the second "B" and "A" are inserted from the right not the left.

Comment: @emanresuA I'm not sure. What do you think? It doesn't make a difference to the two algorithms I've thought of.

Answer (score 4):

## ["Prime" pyramid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254429/prime-pyramid)

Answer (score 4):

## The dating game [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

The bots are looking for love. Can you help them?

### The rules

The goal of this game is find the bot you have the highest comparability with. However, robots, who are inexperienced at dating are unable to tell how well a date went.

In the game, bots take turns "speed dating" some other bot. After each date, each bot chooses whether to get married or to continue dating. If both bots agree to get married both are removed from the dating pool and their compatability rank (100% is if you found the best one, 0% for the worst one) is their final score.

Bots won't be able to tell what the compatibility is, but they can compare dates. For example if bot A went on a date with bot B and C, they'll be able to tell if B or C was more compatible but not by how much.

Bot A's compatibility with B does not equal B's compatibility with A, but they are correlated.

If every bot has dated every other bot, the ordering is shuffled and any remaining bots can try again. However, everyone's final score is reduced by 25% (exponential) for every round they stay single. If a entire round ends without any new marriages the game ends and all remaining bots get a score of 0.

### Example bot

```py
class BetterThanFirst:
    """
    This bot will use its first date as a reference, then marry any bot that's better than it
    """

    def __init__(self, nrof_bots, rng): # rng is a seeded PRNG you can use, no other forms of randomness allowed
        # nrof_bots is the total number of bots playing
        self.first_date = None

    def round_finished(self, nrof_remaining_bots): # the number of bots still in the game
        pass # called if a full round finished, optional

    def date(self, other) -> bool: # Return True if you want to marry this bot, False otherwise
        if self.first_date is None:
            self.first_date = other
        else:
            return other > self.first_date
```

### Other rules

- No IO
- No RNG except via the provided PRNG
- No inspecting other bots. You are only allowed to use the `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, and `is` operators on other bots.
- No exploiting the controller.

Comment: In what order do dates occur? Are all pairs shuffled and then date one-by-one?

Comment: Perhaps instead of `__init__` and `round_finished` both having `nrof_bots` you can have `__init__(self, rng)` and `round_started(self, nrof_bots)`, and then bots don't need to duplicate code to handle the number of bots.

Comment: This seems very similar to [the secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), other than the fact that you can choose to wait for a later round and that candidates might get married before it's your turn to date them.

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes this challenge was very much inspired by the secretary problem, but adapted enough so that the "optimal" solution is unproven, and also to make it multiplayer

Comment: @CommandMaster Bots may need to make decisions based both on the number of remaining bots and the total number of bots.

Answer (score 4):

## [Is it true? Ask Pip!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256166/is-it-true-ask-pip)

Comment: I think I'd stick to the decision-problem defaults and encourage to post non-trivial Pip solution; or post a community-wiki answer with that trivial solution to claim it.

Answer (score 4):

## Is it a Shift matrix?

### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256822/is-this-a-shift-matrix)

Comment: Are other forms of input ok? Like a rectangular matrix if my language supports it?

Comment: @pajonk oops yes thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Transpose binary numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

The input numbers `[34, 7, 109]` can be represented in binary as

```
0100010
0000111
1101101
```

(one number on each line; and padding with zeroes on the left so that all the rows are the same length)

Now transpose this array:

```
001
101
000
001
011
110
011
```

Then convert each row back to decimal to get the output:

```
[1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 6, 3]
```

This is the output.

---

todo: write a proper spec

Is this a duplicate?

Is this interesting?

Would this be more interesting if generalised to an input base `b`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Cosine similarity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259755/cosine-similarity-of-two-vectors)

Answer (score 4):

## Zählen

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259894/zahlen-auf-deutsch-numbers-in-german)

Comment: Nice challenge, the explanation might be a bit better if you listed the numbers up to 23 or so, and then listed just the multiples of ten. This way it could be easier to extrapolate the pattern, especially if there is another pattern that is useful for golfing.

Comment: @Jacob Something like this?

Comment: You are using `zwölf` in the test cases and `zwoelf` in the description. I guess you should either fix this inconsistency or allow both `fuenf/zwoelf/dreissig` and `fünf/zwölf/dreißig`.

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you, that was a mistake, it should be zwoelf.

Answer (score 4):

## Reversed squares

Given an integer n, your task is to determine whether it is a perfect square that when reversed,, is still a perfect square. You may assume n is always positive.

When numbers such as 100 (10x10) are reversed the result may have leading zeros (001) In this case, ignore the leading zeros and treat it as 1 (1x1).

### Test cases

````
1 => True
4 => True
9 => True
441 => True
1234567654321 => True
100 => True

3 => False
25 => False
1784 => False
```
````

Comment: Seems like a fun challenge! But I don't quite get why you're allowing negative numbers. I'd rather let golfers assume the input is positive.

Comment: (Correct me if I'm wrong) Is it always true (1+log(n))%2>1&&sqrt(n)%1==0?

Comment: Yup: https://tio.run/##fcxJDoMgGAXgfU/hRgNpWvkZHBZ4gx6CGOkQAi2g16fTxprQ7fveeze1qDD66z0eli5pmawcEOxPKl6Oxp2BIItxSQcJVfUJw8PHV1aClCSNzgZnpncTaQQYF3VdRD9Pu1/hWenzG57/A8q4aNpGcEb/tAhZ2QbZl7QyYbujIm/Qdnyt6Qk

Comment: I’d say you should post this one now

Comment: @Dadsdy ok posted

Answer (score 4):

## [Numbers that can be negated by reading backwards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262985/numbers-that-can-be-negated-by-reading-backwards)

Comment: Can the output be a list of numeric values `-1`, `0` and `1`, or does "it is allowed to output numbers in balanced ternary" require a T/0/1 string?

Comment: A small inconsistency: the text says "positive integers," but the examples include 0, which is not positive.

Answer (score 4):

## [Continuously Count Consecutive Cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263243/78850)

Comment: I think taking input as a list of strings would be the most standard way of achieving what you want (and returning or printing a list of outputs)

Comment: otherwise you could ask for submissions to be full programs, since it's rare to ask that functions keep state

Comment: of course, that would invalidate answers in languages which cannot take input, which is why I'm leaning towards the list of strings approach

Comment: how is a string different from a boolean array here?

Comment: some relevant defaults for IO: [1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25061/112488), [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/112488), [3](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24639/112488)

Comment: @c-- Taking as a list makes much more sense now. Boolean array would consist of booleans instead of characters, as is the expected format for each input.

Answer (score 4):

### Is this ordering total?

Given a matrix like this:

```
[  0 -1 -1]
[  1  0 -1]
[  1  1  0]
```

Determine if it represents a proper total ordering. A ordering is total if:

- It is transitive for `<` and `>`: \$\forall a, b, c: a<b \wedge b<c \implies a<c \$. For all a,b, c, if a is less than b and b less than c than a is less than c.
- It is transitive for equality: \$\forall a, b, c: a=b \wedge b=c \implies a=c \$. For all `a`,`b`,`c`, if `a` equals `b` and `b` equals `c`, then `a` equals `c`
- It is substitutive \$\forall a,b,c: a=b \wedge b<c \implies a<c\$. For all `a`, `b`, `c`, if `a` equals `b`  and `b` is less than `c` then `a` is also less than `c`.

In this matrix I use `1` to represent less than, `-1` to represent greater than, and `0` to represent equal. However, you are free to use any 3 distinct values (except complete or partial functions)

Given a matrix representing the ordering of every pair, output one value if the ordering is proper and total, and another if not.

You may assume the input is already anti-symetric, eg. M[a][b] == -M[b][a]. No need to check for that.

#### Test cases TBD

Comment: is reflexivity also required? ie, is the matrix [-1] acceptable?

Comment: @RubenVerg `M[a][b] == -M[b][a]` implies `M[a][a] == 0`

Comment: @l4m2 I either missed that line or it was added after I asked

Comment: @RubenVerg I added it in response to your comment

Answer (score 4):

## Assembly capture-the-flag KotH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [machine-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-code)

---

In this KotH, you'll write a program in a custom machine code (or using one of a few provided languages that compile into it) which tries to run a `claim` function as many times as possible to collect points. However, all submissions run on the same "machine", allowing a few ways to defeat competitors:

- Causing a competitor to stop working
- Tricking a competitor to run `claim` on your behalf, using your `flag` (a code you'd pass to `claim`)
- Finding a competitor's flag, and running `capture` on it, which gives their points to you (**meta:** specifics undecided; not sure if it would take all of their points or just some, or if it would leave the competitor running or not, etc.)

Submissions would be programs in a custom machine code, for a 32-bit machine. This could be written by hand, with an assembly language that will be provided, or with a simple C compiler that will be provided. All submissions will have access to four general purpose registers, which are inaccessible to other programs (unless they can trick you into running code that reveals their contents), and their code and data will be placed in a random part of the up to 4 GiB of RAM, accessible to other programs if they can find it.

Games will run until:

1. All but one bot has stopped working, and some number of cycles pass since the second-to-last bot dies (to allow a bot that kills all of its competitors to `claim` some points as the winner)
2. A number of cycles has passed equivalent to \$2.5x+2048\sqrt{b}\$, where \$x\$ is the size of RAM and \$b\$ is the number of bots

(**meta:** not sure if there's a better way to do the game-end conditions)

### Some example strategies

To show how this might have a rather high skill ceiling, here are some example strategies:

- Pretending to be a dumb bot, with an exposed `flag`, as a honeypot. When a competitor injects its own `flag`, you detect that and `capture` it instead
- To avoid the above, read a competitor's code and try to look for things like conditions based on the `flag` or the `capture` syscall before attempting the risky flag injection
- To circumvent the above countermeasure, use self-modification and other tricks to hide what you're doing
- Watching competitors to see if they've found a bot you're targeting, so you can wait until the last minute to `capture` its flag for maximum points
- Tricking other bots into running your own code, and essentially `fork`ing yourself, then attack other bots in parallel
- Placing fake bot source code in random parts of RAM, to waste other bots' time trying to trick a bot that's not there

### Machine code reference (in progress)

There are eight 32-bit general purpose registers, which are interchangeable and have no special properties. Additionally, an instruction pointer and flag register are present, but cannot be directly accessed. The four flags are zero (`z`), negative (`n`), carry (`c`), and overflow (`o`). The instruction set, which takes inspiration primarily from ARM, is as follows:

- `adc`: Add with carry
- `add`: Add
- `adr`: Add signed immediate to the current instruction pointer, and store the result in a register
- `and`: Bitwise AND
- `asr`: Arithmetic shift right
- `b`: Branch
- `b[x|nx]`: Branch if flag `x` is or is not set (any of `c`, `n`, `o`, or `z`, also `p`, where `p = !n && !z`)
- `b[e|ne|gt|lt|ge|le]`: Aliases meant to be used with `cmp`
- `bic`: Bit clear
- `call`: Branch and push current instruction pointer
- `capture`: Capture a flag
- `claim`: Claim a point using a `flag`
- `clz`: Count leading zeros
- `cmn`: Compare negative (same as `add`, but discarding result)
- `cmp`: Compare (same as `sub`, but discarding result)
- `dec`: Decrement
- `div`: Divide
- `inc`: Increment
- `ldr`: Load register from memory
- `lsl`: Bit shift left
- `lsr`: Bit shift right
- `mod`: Modulo
- `mov`: Copy from one register to another
- `mul`: Multiply
- `mul2`: Multiply, outputting to two registers (to fit results overflowing one register)
- `neg`: Negate
- `nop`: No-op
- `not`: Bitwise NOT
- `or`: Bitwise inclusive OR
- `orn`: Bitwise inclusive OR with NOT of 2nd operand
- `pop`: Pop
- `push`: Push
- `ret`: Return (pop a pointer and branch to it)
- `ror`: Rotate bits right
- `sbc`: Subtract with carry
- `sdiv`: Signed divide
- `smul`: Signed multiply
- `smul2`: Signed multiply, outputting to two registers (to fit results overflowing one register)
- `stop`: Stop running; bot is killed
- `str`: Store register in memory
- `sub`: Subtract
- `swp`: Swap register(s) with memory
- `teq`: Test equality (same as `xor`, but discarding result)
- `tst`: Test (same as `and`, but discarding result)
- `xno`: Bitwise XNOR (XOR with NOT of 2nd operand)
- `xor`: Bitwise XOR

Additionally, bots may "trap" one memory address. When this address is written to, an interrupt is issued to the bot. The following instructions exist for this:

- `cli`: Clear interrupt
- `int`: Register an interrupt for a memory address, immediately branching to a specified location when it is written to (this clears an existing interrupt if one exists)
- `sstr`: Stealthy store (allows storing a register to an address without setting off your own interrupt)
- `wfi`: Wait for interrupt (suspends bot until interrupt fires; a suspended bot will not prevent the game-end condition unless it wakes up)
- `wfit`: Wait for interrupt with timeout (same as `wfi`, but will un-suspend the bot if a specified number of cycles passes without an interrupt occurring)

Comment: 1. Make sure to run this in a virtual machine. 2. Can I use the programming language C?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer 1. It's a simulated machine code, so it can't _not_ run in a VM 2. Yes, a simplified C compiler will be provided

Comment: *Writes programme to copy itself to the internet, do `rm "/"` and then copies itself back onto the system.*

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer No access to the outside world will be provided :p

Comment: Then I shall make it copy itself to the parent directory of all the bots and then run the `rm` command.

Comment: Suggestion: Allow trapping a specific instruction rather than a memory address

Comment: @mousetail How would that work? And for what purpose? The goal of the trapped memory addresses is to detect when another bot is, e.g., progressively overwriting your source code

Answer (score 4):

### [Repeat your program to print Fibonacci numbers [tag:code-challenge][tag:source-layout]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264505/repeat-your-program-to-print-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: Are the header and footer also included in the main byte count, or only in the additional fib(n). If it is only in the fib(n) part then adding a two byte header will only increase the score by 1.

Comment: @bsoelch Only in the header, you are correct that a 2 byte header will only count for 1 score, and a 3 byte only for 2 score. May need to adjust the balance to account for golfing languages where 2 bytes might be actually a useful header

Comment: I would suggest to completely get rid of the header and footer, otherwise something similar to `a,b=0,1`  `a,b=b,a+b`  `print(a)` will probably be the shortest solution in most golfing languages

Comment: @bsoelch Many languages may not be able to participate otherwise

Comment: Then I would suggest to add an additional fixed punishment (of for instance 5 bytes) for using the header/footer

Comment: The example Python submission can be [84 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3QzLTlLKV8vJLFDLzFNJz8pMSc4o1NK2ybZWUdJQqlKwLijLzSjRS81JsgTxNrtSc4lSrbG3b7Ghdw1htIGkUq4OkBihgHKvJBTEbagXMKgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Be big more often](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264838/be-big-more-often)

Comment: you should specify whether each number in the input should have a chance of appearing, and it'd also help to be more specific about "larger numbers being chosen more often". I'm pretty sure you mean that if a>b, P(a)>P(b), but it may help to spell it out just to avoid confusion. last question: can the input contain duplicates? anyway neat idea, no idea if its a dupe challenge or not sorry

Comment: @thejonymyster It's ok. I have fixed the issues you have pointed out.

Comment: can we assume that the numbers are positive

Comment: @bsoelch Yes, you can.

Comment: Similar question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89621/random-golf-of-the-day-7-a-distinctly-random-character

While not exactly the same, most of the answers there would also solve this question after a sort.

Comment: @chunes So is it a duplicate?

Comment: Personally I'd say no, but be prepared for others to disagree.

Answer (score 4):

## There's more than one way to do it

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Cops: Pick a freely available programming language, and pick a function on the integers (i.e. given one integer as input, it produces one integer as output). Then write \$N\$ programs/functions in your language that implement it and are all the same length. \$N\$ must be \$\geq 2\$. Post your language, a description of the function, and \$N-1\$ of the implementations.

Robbers: Pick a cop's post. You can crack the post by finding another program/function in the same language, of equal length, that implements the same function.

(Note that a solution of *lesser* length, i.e. a golf, is **not** a valid crack, although in most languages it's easy to pad a solution out to the desired length.)

If a cop's post is not cracked within one week after it's posted, it may be marked as safe. The cop should edit the post to read "Safe" and reveal their omitted solution. Until a post is so edited, it can still be cracked, even if it is more than a week old. A safe cop post is worth \$N\$ points, where \$N\$ is the number of solutions in the post. Robbers receive one point for each cop post they crack.

### Details

Cops may use a function on the nonnegative or positive integers if they prefer. If your cop post uses one of these restricted domains, please say so in your post. Your solutions (and robbers' solutions) are allowed to produce different results for inputs outside your chosen domain, as long as they produce identical results for inputs inside the domain.

[Cops may measure the length of a program in any way they choose. Some possibilities are bytes, characters, codels, non-whitespace characters, etc. Please specify how you are counting length in your post.] - I'm not sure about this rule. See below.

---

Sandbox questions:

- Is this concept interesting?
- Does the scoring make sense? Are there ways for the cops to game the scoring system to get arbitrarily high scores? Would it be better if the \$N\$ solutions were forbidden to have any characters/bytes in common? (But that would cause problems for a lot of languages that aren't golflangs, which I'd rather avoid.)
- Is the "choose your own length measure" rule reasonable, or does it open the door to weird exploits? I suspect that more-flexible counting methods like "number of occurrences of `n` and `Q`" will just cause problems for the cop, since they will allow robbers to construct elaborate workarounds using characters that aren't counted.

Comment: You should maybe clarify what you mean with restricted domains. You mention restriction to the positive integers, would restricting the function to a finite range (like `-2147483648`to `2147483647`) be also allowed.

Comment: One problem might be that `lambda a:a&1`, `lambda b:b&1`,..., `lambda z:z&1` are technically different programs. You should probably add a rule against purely syntactic changes.

Comment: @bsoelch Both good points, thanks. I think it won't work to ban the "technically different programs" approach outright (how to define when a difference is "purely syntactic" in a way that's general enough to apply to all programming languages?), but maybe I can modify the scoring system to disincentivize highly similar programs.

Comment: By finding, you mean already implemented in the function's standard library, or programming a solution in the chosen language?

Comment: @ToAskOrNotToAsk The latter: writing a program or function.

Answer (score 4):

## The Legend of Koth Episode 1: WANTED

Alright. The [WumpusWars](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25889#25889) project turned out to be more than I can swallow, so I had to give it up. If you're interested in hosting the competition yourself go ahead: it would be very fun.

I instead thought of a simpler-to-implement King of the Hill! I plan to make a series ([yeah I love series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263049/cops-fast-and-golfiest-season-1-the-lord-of-the-strings/)) of King-of-the-Hill challenges based primarily on metagame and interactions, and named it The Legend of Koth. Here comes Episode 1: WANTED. Hope u like it ;-)

====================

Backstory: A long long time ago in a galaxy far far away, on the planet of code-o-sphere, a civil war broke out between CGCC and CRSE (*). Deserted wasteland spammed with unreadable Esolang code and 100-line-long docstrings were the remains of most once bustling cities of the code-o-sphere.

When the war was over, some survivors settled in the town of Koth. They had magnificent plans: of rebuilding civilization! Equality and freedom for everyone!

... until they found out how hard it was to build a society from scratch. By that time, it was too late.

The town had employed too many vigilantes and trusted them with great power. And so, echoing the lessons learned by habitants of a remote little insignificant blue planet, they found -- the hard way -- that power corrupts, and absolute power corrupts absolutely. Now, the vigilantes are fighting, to see who is the best!

The pains of the previous war eventually convinced them to control the warfare to a relatively small scale: the vigilante factions will send representatives to see who is the best! Now the towns' once beautiful walls and buildings are covered with posters...:

WANTED. Dead, undead, or preferably deader than dead, but definitely not alive, thank you very much.

(*) Note: For those who don't understand the joke, CRSE (Code Review Stack Exchange) is often joked to be CGCC's arch-nemesis because they value readability over conciseness and hacky stuff, while most challenges here want the opposite.

Disclaimer: I am politically strictly neutral and indifferent (this is part of my moral principle) so the backstory bears no relations to real-life politics or history. It's simply a humorous mish-mash of some relevant tropes.

====================

The rule: this is mainly inspired by King of the Holster.

You can distribute your 10 initial points between HP, defense, and reputation. Your HP is your HP point plus 10, and your defense is the probability of blocking, calculated by defense points times 0.1. Your reputation is simply equal to your reputation points times 10.

The basic system is similar to the Holster game. You have 1 ammo at the beginning. During each round, you can (1) refill 1 ammo, (2) heal 1 HP, (3) attack someone, or (4) post a wanted poster.

Attacking costs 1 ammo. The attacked guy chooses a random real number between 0 and 1, and if is smaller than his defense he blocks, meaning that the damage he takes is randomly decided from 0-2. Otherwise he takes 3-5 damage. Killing someone who isn't wanted gives you 20 reputation points.

Wanted posters are publically visible. You can choose to cost x of your reputation to post the poster (no refunds, similar to the bounty system on Stack Exchange). If the guy on the wanted poster is killed the one who killed him has his reputation increased by 20+x.

The winner is the one with the most reputation -- not necessarily the last man standing. If no attacks are made for 10 consecutive turns or only one man is surviving then the game ends.

====================

Good luck and happy coding!

Leaderboard: (will be updated as soon as I can)

Achievements: (all achievements are hidden so no achievement conditions are revealed until someone gets them)

Comment: How do you plan to have the bot controller? In Python, or another language? Other than that solid KOTH

Comment: @noodleman In python. Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: "rolls a dice" -> "generates a random float between 0 and 1"?

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks. Changed.

Comment: Can multiple posters be posted on the same person? I'm guessing they just add?

Comment: @CommandMaster The bounty just adds on but you can see who wants someone dead

Answer (score 4):

## [Decrypt an autokey cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265627/119678)

Comment: It might be simpler to allow answers to work directly with 0-25 numbers, and not require a transformation to/from letters

Comment: I feel like that may defeat the purpose of the cipher itself, although I did notice that `ord` and `chr` took up many bytes when I tried to do a python solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Write a set as a union of ranges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265670/write-a-set-as-a-union-of-ranges)

Comment: I assume this is [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @noodleman Yes (filler)

Comment: "you can use any reasonable format that unambiguously represents a single range" does this allow formats that "encode" the range as, say for example, a start value, and end value, and a step size?

Comment: @thejonymyster Yes, that was my intention. I'll add in a specific example

Answer (score 4):

## [Output greater than without the previous character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265797/108687)

Comment: In the current form `21` will be the optimal solution in all languages allowing implicit output (assuming the empty program does not print a number)

Comment: The implicit output trick works up to `98765432310` (10 bytes). As long as nobody finds an infinite family of programs `code-bowling` should be fine.

Comment: Why characters over bytes? It is generally a bad choice since characters have nothing to do how information is stored. What stops submissions from choosing ASCII and maximising the characters per byte?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Because the radiation is on the characters, not the bytes. And your point doesn’t really make sense for code-bowling, I don’t really want people shoving high-codepoint characters just to boost their score. I’d it was code-golf then bytes would might sense but then i’d probably want to make the radiation be on the bytes. If you come up with a good example of this being bad I might change it though.

Comment: Scratch the thing I said about code-golf, I can’t edit the comment anymore. Bytes would make sense if I made the radiation be on the bytes but I wasn’t planning to do that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Complement an infinite list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265699/complement-an-infinite-list)

Comment: Another input option that feels maybe implied by the second bullet point but could be worth spelling out is a stateful function/callback that takes no arguments to produce the next number but doesn't conform to any language-internal notion of an iterator.

Answer (score 4):

## [Help, I can't bloody well memorize this number!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266208/help-i-cant-bloody-well-memorize-this-number)

Comment: Nice challenge, and nice PFP! :p

Answer (score 4):

## [The too-short urinal problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/266444/108687)

Comment: (Inspired by @97.100.97.109's sandboxed challenge https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26101/108687)

Answer (score 4):

### Golf Transmission

As in, the 5 speed transmission from the original VW Golf GTI.

Print the transmission pattern in as few bytes as possible.

```
1  3  5
|  |  | 
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: this pun was too good to pass up

Comment: Would extra whitespace that doesn't affect display be allowed? Would returning an array of strings be OK?

Comment: ok i forgot to change this but its been up for like 2 weeks

Answer (score 4):

## English Golf

Your challenge is to golf some English text by replacing some words with their contractions. Here is a list of the contractions you need to support:

| Words | Contraction |
| --- | --- |
| are not | aren't |
| can not | can't |
| could have | could've |
| could not | couldn't |
| dare not | daren't |
| did not | didn't |
| does not | doesn't |
| do not | don't |
| had not | hadn't |
| has not | hasn't |
| have not | haven't |
| he had | he'd |
| he is | he's |
| he will | he'll |
| I am | I'm |
| I had | I'd |
| I have | I've |
| I will | I'll |
| is not | isn't |
| it is | it's |
| it will | it'll |
| let us | let's |
| might have | might've |
| might not | mightn't |
| must have | must've |
| must not | mustn't |
| need not | needn't |
| shall not | shan't |
| she had | she'd |
| she is | she's |
| she will | she'll |
| should have | should've |
| should not | shouldn't |
| that is | that's |
| that will | that'll |
| there had | there'd |
| there is | there's |
| they are | they're |
| they had | they'd |
| they have | they've |
| they will | they'll |
| was not | wasn't |
| we are | we're |
| we had | we'd |
| we have | we've |
| we will | we'll |
| were not | weren't |
| will not | won't |
| would have | would've |
| would not | wouldn't |
| you are | you're |
| you had | you'd |
| you have | you've |
| you will | you'll |

This is just a minimal list but you can support other common (please show your source) English contractions should you so wish. Most of them have one of am/are/is, had, have/has, not or will as the second word, except for "let us".

If there is a choice of contraction you can choose either or go for a double contraction e.g. "couldn't've".

The contraction should keep the case of the words, e.g. "Let us go!" becomes "Let's go!".

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: Maybe some example when pure suffix replacement would fail(maybe "will" as noun?)

Comment: @l4m2 Well this is an oversimplification anyway for instance in questions the words are in a different order.

Answer (score 4):

## Derive an MIU string

The MU puzzle in Douglas Hofstadter's *Gödel, Escher, Bach* involves a simple formal system called "MIU". It works as follows:

- `MI` is an MIU-string
- If `xI` is an MIU-string, then so is `xIU`.
- If `Mx` is an MIU-string, then so is `Mxx`.
- If `xIIIy` is an MIU-string, then so is `xUy`.
- If `xUUy` is an MIU-string, then so is `xy`.

Your task, given an MIU-string, is to output a derivation of that string starting with `MI` and ending with the input string.

You can assume that the input is in fact a valid MIU-string and not something illegal like `MCMLXVIII` or (spoiler) `MU`.

Instead of taking input as strings of `MIU`, you can choose to take input as arbitrary precision integers using the digits `3` for `M`, `1` for `I` and `0` for `U`. In that case your output would start with `31`, which represents `MI`.

Example:

```
MI
MII
MIIII
MUI
MUIU
MUIUUIU
MUIIU
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34441/31625). Personally a bit surprised there doesn't seem to be a dupe.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Unless there's way to solve possibility using some other properties, they'd be too similar

Comment: @l4m2 Personally, I think the guarantee of reachability makes them sufficiently different. It is possible that brute force is still the golfiest solution, but even then, not having to handle the fail case seems like a significant factor. I could certainly be wrong, though.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Don't a trivial upperbound exist?

Answer (score 4):

## Classify a Coxeter group

In this challenge you will take as input a Coxeter matrix representing a Coxeter system. Your program will then classify it as one of the following:

- Spherical
- Euclidean
- Compact
- Paracompact
- Hypercompact

Your program should output one of 5 distinct values depending on which category the input falls into.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). The goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Spherical (finite)

A Coxeter system is spherical iff it is finite.

### Euclidean (affine)

A Coxeter system is Euclidean iff the determinant of its Schläfli matrix is 0.

TODO better definition of this, or explain what a Schläfli matrix is.

### Compact

A Coxeter system is compact iff every strict minor of its Coxeter matrix gives a finite group (and it is not itself spherical or Euclidean). That is every way to remove one generator from the system gives a spherical group.

### Paracompact

A Coxeter system is compact iff every strict minor of its Coxeter matrix gives a spherical or Euclidean group (and it is not sperical, Euclidean or compact). That is every way to remove one generator from the group gives a spherical or Euclidean group group.

### Hypercompact

If a Coxeter system is not any of the above then it is called **hypercompact**.

### Sandbox

I had this idea, but haven't had enough time to write up a specification. I'll explain things better later, define a Coxeter system and give the enumerations of each class.

Answer (score 4):

## [Construct the Constructability sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267394/66833)

Answer (score 4):

### Cyclically Sort a List

Given a list of Integers greater than zero, Sort each of the unique values in ascending order, then repeat the process on the remaining duplicate values and append.

Example:

```
[1,5,2,2,8,3,5,2,9] ==> [1,2,3,5,8,9,2,5,2]
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Answer (score 4):

## Approximately Detect Primes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given a number from 1 up to 100, your submission should decide whether it is a prime or not. But it is allowed to make up to 5 mistakes, that is, 95 numbers must be classified correctly.

Comment: This is a nice idea, though I imagine somebody will come up with a very simple clever solution and everyone else will just port it

Comment: FYI the obvious solution seems to be `n%2*n%3*n%5!=0` which fails 6 times

Comment: @noodleman Yes I do fear the first, but usually the first few solutions are the creative ones. I did test a whole bunch of the simple modulo solutions, including yours, but I got 8 fails. I must have gotten something wrong D: (My thinking was that with 2,3,5,7 you should be good enough, and I thought with this number you might also have other solutions.)

Comment: Ok I did make a mistake, I wanted it to be between the (2,3,5) (6 fails) and (2,3,5,7)  (4 fails) solution. I updated it accordingly.

Comment: I think at 5 fails, in a lot of languages this isn’t going to be very different from a plain primality test. Maybe the scoring criteria could be more like length + # of failures?

Comment: (can’t edit after 5 minutes) length * (# of failures / 100)? Similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265055/108687, just a thought it might be ok as is

Comment: How about you take a different set of numbers to test approximately? OEIS is full of sequences which are neither build-ins of many languages nor follow a too simple formula nor show an obvious pattern. This could result in more creative answers, even late surprising answers.

Comment: There's a 9-byte Python expression I expect most non-golflangs will copy. It can almost be 8 bytes but that leaves 6 errors.

Answer (score 4):

[Name the Dutch ancestor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268818/name-the-dutch-ancestor)

Comment: No problems with the question; I like it a lot. But I just want to say the auto-translated names on the linked page are very fun! "for noble tribal old-great-grandparents", "common stem oldenchantedgrandparents" and such.

Answer (score 4):

## Decompile

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

In this challenge "cops" will write a computer program and compile it. They will post the result of the compilation (for simplicity we will just call this the "binary"), along with a description of the compilation (what compiler was used, what flags were used etc.), but not the source.

"Robbers" will then try to find source code that compiles into the same result.

The goal of the cops is to make as short of an executable as possible without being solved by the robbers, and the goal of the robbers is to crack as many cops answers as possible.

### Specifics

There are a lot of specifics here to deal with.

- First let's be clear that the robber does not have to find the exact program used by the cop, as long as the program the robber presents compiles to the binary with the given description.
- I'm going to require that the cops program consist of only 1 file. The contents of this file will be referred to as "the source".
- When describing the compilation process the cop should include everything variable that affects the binary other than the source.  A non-exhaustive list of things that may affect the binary is:

  - The version of the compiler used.
  - The architecture of the machine used.
  - Flags provided to the compiler.
  - The name or any other metadata of the file containing the source.
  - The number of times the compiler is run. (Yes unfortunately there are compilers that are not idempotent.)
  - The exact time the compiler was run.
- While we call it a binary for simplicity, the cop's program can be compiled to any target. You can even present something that might normally be considered an intermediate stage of compilation.
- The binary can do anything non-malicious. Don't write something that would do damage to the system it is being run on, but other than that you may do anything or nothing at all. Your binary may error, and the compiler may error while producing it.

### Vulnerable, cracked, safe and revealed

Cops' posts here can have 4 different states:

1. Vulnerable
2. Cracked
3. Safe
4. Revealed

All cops' posts start as *vulnerable*.  If a robber finds and posts a solution to a *vulnerable* post they will receive 1 point and the post will become *cracked*.  If a post lasts 10 days in *vulnerable* without being solved it automatically becomes *safe*.  A cop with a *safe* post may choose to reveal **A** and **B** and their *safe* post will become *revealed*.  A robber can still solve a *safe* post, if they do they receive a point and the post becomes *revealed*.

Only *revealed* posts are eligible for scoring. Robbers are only permitted to solve *vulnerable* and *safe* posts.

Answer (score 3):

## Count Syllables

The goal of this challenge is to write a program that can count the syllables in a word as accurately as possible.

### Input

On STDIN, your program will receive a number X followed by X lines, each containing a single word. Simple enough. (*Should there be a limit on the size of X?*) The words will come from [this list](http://web.mit.edu/kilroi/Public/bot/wordlist).

```
4
challenge
to
count
syllables
```

### Output

Your output should be to STDOUT and have X lines. On each line should be the number of syllables counted in that word.

```
2
1
1
3
```

## Scoring

To score you program, it will receive a long secret list of words to test. All programs will receive the same list of words. For each word, the number of syllables that your program got wrong will be added to the score of the program. If it output a 4 or a 2 when the word had 3 syllables, then one point will be added. If it said a 15 instead of a 3, then 12 points will be added to the score. The lower the score, the better.

For example, if for the above input your program output `3 2 2 2` (which would be produced by a program that counts strings of vowels), then the program would receive a score of 2.

## Rules

Your program should not access any external files (such as the word list). Also, your program should be no more than 5,000 bytes long (*is this a reasonable limit?*).

The winner will be the person whose program has the lowest score, therefor the most accurate syllable counter. The deadline for submissions is [some time at least a month away].

## Suggestions

I am open to all constructive criticism. Is 5,000 bytes a reasonable limit for the program size? How long should the official scoring test be? How long should the deadline be?

Comment: This has one major flaw: the output is subjective. How many syllables do these words have? Every; victory; hierarchy; desire; oil; hour; poem. The only real way I see to work around this is for you to produce a marked-up version of the word list.

Comment: I was really worried about that, and I don't see a way around it.

Comment: I personally would love to see more language processing challenges. I agree with @PeterTaylor on the difficulty of some words. Perhaps taking a specific text(s) and identifying explicitly in the challenge which words will have how many syllables?

Comment: @PeterTaylor ...Or maybe you could filter ambiguous words out of the reference list?

Comment: What's the point of the first line of input?

Comment: If you provide a reference list, A hyphenated reference list, and hide a secret list which may or may not include members of the reference list, this would  be a reasonable challenge

Comment: Do you plan to post this? If not, I'd be happy to adopt it. (If you don't respond within two weeks, by community standards, I'm allowed to do so.)

Comment: The example of inaccurate program that would score 2 - did you mean to output 3 1 1 2 rather than 3 2 2 2?

Comment: A reference list could be dynamic: potential contestants can ask for words of their choice to be added to the list. They won't know what's on the secret list but will try to make their programs as accurate as possible (according to your syllable count) so they should always be able to ask for specific words they are not sure about. Of course, you could make it in different language. In my language, Slovene, it's much clearer how many syllables words have. How about Solresol, haha!

Comment: I am going to adopt this if you don''t respond

Answer (score 3):

### Play Simple 2-Dimensional Minecraft

Recently I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdnO1QZJ--M&feature=youtube_gdata_player) of "HansLemurson" showing a computer that was built in minecraft, which runs minecraft. He is playing minecraft on a computer that was built in minecraft that is running on his computer. To be specific, it is a two dimensional version with an 8x8 grid of cells. There is gravity, block placement, and even jumping. It is worth noting that the computer is single purpose. The same person has built programmable computers, but making them single purpose allows the computer to be much smaller.

### Details

The minecraft world is an 8x8 grid (one horizontal and one vertical dimension). The grid is comprised of either Xs (representing blocks) or empty spaces. The player is an X that is blinking on and off about once every second.

There are two modes in the game, controlled by a toggle switch. The first mode is movement. This is controlled by a WASD-like button arrangement. If the player chooses to move left/right/down, the computer checks to see if the space immediately in that direction is empty. If so, then the player moves into that space.

If the player chooses to move up, then the computer checks that the block underneath the player is solid. If so, then the player moves upward two units. Notice that this can propel the player into a solid block. If this happens, the player is obscured by the solid block, but can still move to an empty block next to him. When the player is inside on a solid block, the game continues as if the block isn't there, although the block is still there once the player leaves it.

After each move, the player falls down one unit if there is empty space there. This simulates gravity. This is also why moving up moves up two units, so that the gravity makes a net movement of up one unit. Gravity does not cause the player to fall all of the way to the ground, just one unit.

The second mode is block placement. In this mode, the same exact WASD buttons are used. Instead of moving the player, they toggle the state of the block in that direction. If the player presses "left" and there is a block there, then the block is destroyed. If there is not a block there, then a block is placed. Again after this move, the player is again subject to gravity. The blocks are not subject to falling.

Toggling the toggle switch does not count as a move, and does not invoke gravity.

The game board is a torus, so all actions (movement, block creation) can wrap around the board. The board does not scroll with the player. The player moves, and the blocks stay in the same place.

### The challenge

You challenge is to write the shortest program that simulates this game. Your program should display and update the map correctly (with Xs as blocks, and with the blinking player). It should accept input from a button that toggles the state and four buttons for movement and actions.  This is code golf.

There are imaginary bonus points for adding more features (block types, game size, etc) to your game.

### Suggestions?

Comment: With more complicated challenges I find that it helps to do a reference implementation so that you have a very concrete idea of how much work is involved. Aside from that, I like it.

Comment: Is the blink rate selected to fit with the ANSI escape sequence? Either way I would explicitly allow that, because it's the obvious way to do it on compatible terminals.

Comment: The blink rate wasn't selected to be anything specific. I think that I will broaden the restriction. Maybe any blink rate between 3 blinks per second to 1 blink every 2 seconds.

Comment: @programmer5000 No, for two main reasons: First, challenges *can* go extended periods of time in the sandbox before they are posted and/or adopted.  In the past I've posted challenges after not touching them for 4 years.  Second, deleting this answer will not reduce lag, as deleted answers are still present, simply not visible.  Users with sufficient rep will see all 4040 answers in the sandbox, and you will too once you earn the "view deleted answers" privilege.

Answer (score 3):

### Bad Voice Recognition Calculator

**Overview**:

Let's say you've decided to operate your computer using voice recognition software, but unfortunately you did a horrible job researching the various products out there and chose a package that does not recognize numbers as numerals, only words. (i.e. "one" (spoken) == "one" (typed), not "1".) Rather than spend more money to get another option, you decide to make do. Now you want to use the computer's calculator, but this poses a problem, since your machine doesn't know how to add "one plus one".

**Objective**:

Implement a basic calculator that will read in a string of the written-out equation, perform the correct calculations, then return the result in its text form. **Your code should be as short as possible; this is code golf.**

**Rules/Constraints**:

- Input/output will be using your preferred method (`STDIN`, `ARGV`, etc.).
- Your calculator must be able to handle input and output within the billions (non-inclusive) `-1,000,000,000 < i < 1,000,000,000`, but you may expand to more if you wish.
- Decimal values and/or parts must be accepted (`0 < i < 1`) up to 3 places/digits.

  - When calculating answers, proper rounding must be used, so `"three point one four one five nine two six"` must be returned as `"three point one four two"`.
- Basic calculator functions required:

  - `"Add"/"Plus"/"Sum"/"And" (+)`
  - `"Subtract"/"Minus"/"Remove" (-)`
  - `"Multiply"/"Times" (*)`
  - `"Divide"/"Divided"/"Divide by"/"Divided by" (/)`
  - `"Raise"/"Exponent"/"Power"/"To the power of" (^)`
  - `"<Base>Root"/"<Base>Radical" (√)`
  - `"Point"/"Decimal" (.)`
  - `"Pi" (π)`
- All strings in the list above must be accounted for in your code, capitalization does not matter.
- Numbers may be presented as their full value (`"one thousand"`) or by digit (`one zero zero zero`).
- Negative numbers may be assigned using `"Minus"` or `"Negative"`.

  - The string `"Minus"` bust be accounted for as an operator and identifier. (see example)
- `"And"` is only acceptable as an operator, not as part of a named number.

  - <strike>`"one hundred and one"`</strike>
  - `"one hundred one"`
- `"a"` or the absence of a number does not equate to any number; all numbers will be explicitly accounted for in the program input.

  - `"a hundred"` does not equate to `"one hundred"` and is not a valid input.
- No more than 2 terms will be used.

  - `"one plus one minus one"` will not be implemented.
- If an invalid input is supplied, your function/program should handle the error and exit gracefully with an error description.

**Example I/O**:

- `"one add one"` --> `"two"`
- `"five thousand thirty four subtract ten thousand six hundred"` --> `"negative five thousand five hundred sixty six"`

  - *Alternatively*: `"five zero three four subtract one zero six zero zero"`
- `"three root twenty seven"` --> `"three"`
- `"ten minus minus ten"` --> `"twenty"`

  - *Alternatively*: `"ten subtract negative ten"`

---

### Sandbox Questions:

1. Is this too basic/complicated? (I'm assuming some languages will handle this much more simply than the method I have in my head...)
2. Does the title fit?
3. Are there any constraints that should be added/lifted?
4. Are any more examples needed for clarification?

Thanks for your input, guys!

Comment: Not everyone says numbers the same way. Does the parser have to treat the following as equivalent? "negative one hundred five", "minus one hundred five", "negative one hundred and five", "minus one hundred and five", "negative a hundred five", "negative a hundred and five", ...?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I had had a similar thought re: operators. (`"plus"` versus `"add"`, etc.) I think it would be more interesting to account for all, but given the wide variety of possible inputs, it may generally be better to limit the options to a specifically defined set (which I have yet to define).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added some of these details. Please let me know if there's anything unclear about them.

Comment: I don't spot any ambiguities in the parser. There is still an ambiguity relating to decimals, though. What precision should be used? Also, I notice now that there's no winning condition. Is this intended to be code-golf? (Ugh - tons of strings which will have to be hard-coded in most languages. I expect Perl has a suitable parser already in CPAN, though...)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't know where I went... I've updated the spec. re: decimal places and objective.

Comment: @PeterTaylor https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Words2Nums

Answer (score 3):

### Chess move

**The Challenge**

Write a program that gets a string containing a chessmove and a chessboard as input, and then outputs the chessboard.

**Requirements**

The chess move will have this format:

```
<from square><to square>[<promoted to>]
```

Examples:

```
d2d4
f8g7
a7a8R
```

The chessboard format is not fixed, but there must be a 1 to 1 relation between the board and the string to represent the board. Also the format of the input must bet the same as the format of the output. Two suggestions of what it could look like:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr pppppppp 00000000 00000000  00000000  00000000 PPPPPPPP RNBQKBNR
```

It is not required to store anything except the location of the pieces, and validity of moves can be assumed.

**Scoring**

Base score is character count (assuming your program can move pieces for all moves)

Bonus multipliers:

- If the program updates the promoted piece, divide by 2
- If the program also moves the rook when castling, divide by 2
- If the program also removes the pawn when capturing en passent, divide by 2

The moves, and castling & en passent in particular are explaned [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess#Gameplay).

So basically writing a 100 character solution for the base problem gives the same score as an 800 character solution with all bonus multipliers.

**Examples**

If you would choose to use one of the board formats above, your input would look like one of these strings:

```
e2e4 rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR

e2e4 rnbqkbnr pppppppp 00000000 00000000  00000000  00000000 PPPPPPPP RNBQKBNR
```

Your corresponding output string would then be one of these:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr pppppppp 00000000 00000000  0000P000  00000000 PPPP0PPP RNBQKBNR
```

Comment: Before I get on to more specific criticisms: as presented, without the bonus this is too trivial to be interesting. I suggest removing some flexibility: require Fen notation for the board position and algebraic notation for the move, and making the current bonus options mandatory. On specifics: it's not clear why you talk about storage; and the board position notations you suggest don't include enough information to know whether en passant is possible.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree that compared to chess programs this may be trivial, but I would like to make it a golf challenge. Compared to the hot code golf questions this is quite elaborate already in its basic form. (For a good solution the board design may need to be changed drastically). It is true that there is no attention to the legality of moves (whether it is possible to capture en passent) but for a mere viewer this is not required so I am not too worried about this. So far the chess questions seem to get very few answers as they tend to be complex and I hope to offer relatively easy entry.

Comment: Your point about en passant is valid - you had said in the spec to not worry about legality. I'll try to convince you of my first point: without the bonus, this reduces to: a) parse first four characters into (col 1, row 1, col 2, row 2); b) take board as a 64-char string; c) `board[8*row_2+col_2] := board[8*row_1+col_1]; board[8*row_1+col_1] := ' '; print board`. This is trivial compared to any *good* golf question. (Note that the hot questions at the moment are neither golf questions nor good questions).

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to vote to delete this.

Answer (score 3):

## Create a program with "exact repetition" in its source code

The task is to create a program, with the following restrictions placed on the
printable ASCII characters in the source code: choose some `k > 0`.

- Every *non-alphabetic* character has to appear **exactly** `k` times.
- Every *alphabetic* character has to appear **at most** `k` times.

  - This rule differs from the former in order to avoid boring dummy
    identifiers while still making it a challenge to choose good library
    functions to call.

Character set definitions used:

- *Non-alphabetic characters* are `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~` and '`' (backtick).
- *Alphabetic characters* are `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Note that no restriction is placed on characters outside of the range of
printable ASCII characters (including control codes, tabs, newlines, higher
unicode codepoints, etc).

What the program does is up to you; be creative.  Some general guidelines:

- Programs that do something interesting might have better chances, although
  more impressive code structure (i.e. fewer comments) is also beneficial.
- Stuffing excess characters in comments is boring, and should be avoided/is
  discouraged.
- Dead/no-op code isn't terribly interesting either, but is probably
  unavoidable and at least has to conform to the language's grammar.

This is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest): whatever has the most upvotes at Feb 1, 2014
gets accepted as the winner.

---

#### Example answer (C)

```c
#
#
/*$$@``*/_[]={9.};main() {printf("He%clo \
world!%c\
",2^7&!8.&~1|~-1?4|5?0x6C:48:6<3>2>=3<++_[0],'@'^79-5);}
```

Prints "Hello world!" (adapted from an answer to another question).  Probably wouldn't score a lot (since what it does isn't terribly interesting).  Each of
the non-alphabetic characters appear exactly twice, and no alphabetic
character appears more than twice.

---

**For meta**: I want to post this, but I'm worrying that "do something interesting" might give too little guidance and the question won't receive many answers.. thoughts? Is it good as-is, or should I come up with some task that one should be required to implement (and possibly change the ruling to code-challenge, with `length + 2^(characters-in-comments)` as the score)?

Answer (score 3):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game) [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

## Black Box

Your task is to analyze a given situation for [the game Black Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Box_%28game%29). Given a sequence of guesses and answers, your program is to either print the solution or suggest the next move.

### The game

The board consists of 8×8 cells, with edges labeled like this:

*I'll probably create nice images here, particularly to make sure that the squares of the board are really square.*

```
 abcdefgh
i        I
j        J
k        K
l        L
m        M
n        N
o        O
p        P
 ABCDEFGH
```

The player shoots rays into the interior of the box, where they might get deflected, reflected or absorbed. He is told the position where the ray leaves the black box again, and from that has to deduce the positions of 4 atoms inside the black box.

*I'll have to include more of the game rules here, but for now [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Box_%28game%29).*

## Input and output

Input is a sequence of line, each consisting of two characters. The first denotes the point where the ray of light enters the black box, the second the place where it comes out again. In the case of a reflection, both characters will be equal. In the case of a hit, the second character will be `-`.

If the input is enough to fully determine the locations of the atoms, then output should be four lines giving the coordinates of each atom. The lines should be two lower case characters each, the first giving the row and the second giving the column of the found solution. The atom positions must be printed in lexicographical order.

If the input is consistent with more than one set of atom positions, then the output should consist of a single line containing a single character, which is the location where the next ray should be shot. That location has to be chosen in such a way that it can help find the solution. This is the case unless all of the atom positions consistent with the input so far would produce the same output for this next ray as well.

Your output has to be terminated by a newline character.

## Examples

Let's take the atom configuration the Wikipedia article uses as an example as well:

```
 abcdefgh
i        I
j        J
k O    O K
l        L
m        M
n   O    N
o        O
p      O P
 ABCDEFGH
```

If the input were

```
cf
D-
Em
HH
Co
```

then the output should be

```
kb
kg
nd
pg
```

but if the input were only

```
Em
HH
```

then the output might be for example

```
K
```

### Scoring

This is code golf, so shortest answer wins. However, I'll only accept answers which are practical in so far as they compute their result in reasonable time. I'd say no more than five minutes on my system where I'll evaluate the answers, and I'll simply hope that correct solutions will be much faster and incorrect ones much slower, so that the speed of my system doesn't make a difference. A submission which gives a wrong answer for one of my test cases will be disqualified until it gets fixed. I will probably point out the problem in a comment to that post.

Answer (score 3):

This is my first try at writing a challenge. Please let me know how I can improve it.

## Roman Calculator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Create a basic calculator for Roman numerals.

#### Requirements

- Supports `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`
- Input and output should expect only one prefix per symbol (i.e. 3 can't be `IIV` because there is two `I`'s before `V`)
- Input and output should be left to right in order of value, starting with the largest (i.e. 19 = `XIX` not `IXX`, 10 is larger than 9)
- Left to right, no operator precedence, as if you were using a hand calculator.
- Supports whole positive numbers input/output between 1-4999 (no need for V̅)
- No libraries that do roman numeral conversion for you

#### For you to decide

- Case sensitivity
- Spaces or no spaces on input
- What happens if you get a decimal output. Truncate, no answer, error, etc..
- What to do for output that you can't handle. Negatives or numbers to large to be printed.

#### Extra Credit

- **-20** - Handle up to 99999 or larger (numbers with a vinculum)

Sample input/output

```
XIX + LXXX                 (19+80)
XCIX

XCIX + I / L * D + IV      (99+1/50*500+7)
MIV
```

The shortest code wins.

Comment: You might want to be explicit about which variants of Roman numerals need to be supported. For example, do I have to understand `IV` as 4, or can I require that it be written as `IIII`? And what about, say, writing 8 as `IIX` instead of `VIII`, 19 as `IXX` or `XVIV` instead of `XIX`, or 99 as `IC` instead of `XCIX`? (All these variants have, AFAIK, been used classically.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thanks. I modified the question to be slightly more specific about that.

Comment: I think that using IV, IX, IC, XC, etc. should be alright, but only allow one prefix.  Also, 19 should be written XIX, not IXX.  One other thing, can we assume that the operators will be separated by a space, or no?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Comment: 1. I don't need to handle `I/III` but need to handle `I/III+II/III`? 2. For the extra can I output maybe `[V]` for 5000?

Comment: @programmer5000 it was posted to main awhile ago. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/create-a-roman-numeral-calculator

Answer (score 3):

## Create a calendar

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)

We all know HDD-space is precious and bandwidth is expensive, therefore it is best to reduce the size of your executables. Let's start with your calendar:

Your task is to build a calendar app in at most 512 bytes. The calendar must at least support the following features, but additional features may gain you additional upvotes:

- It must be able to show the current month with the current day highlighted
- The user must be able to find out the week day of each day

Rules:

- Maximum code length is 512 bytes (counted as UTF-8 without BOM)
- You may subtract the bootstrapping code (i.e. `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in C or `<?php` in PHP) and imports from the final size to allow for more verbose languages to be in
- You may use standard time / date functions of your programming language, as long as they don't allow you to output a ready to use calendar
- No network access (I said bandwidth is expensive!)
- Voters decide on the amount of features / look and feel / creativity

---

This needs a tag for the size restriction, any suggestions?

Comment: "bandwidth is expensive" <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Comment: Seems rather close to [Output: Calendar Month](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15738/194)

Comment: Who decides what counts as bootstrapping code? It seems odd to arbitrarily exclude code like that, and the examples you gave can be golfed a *lot*: they're more or less equivalent to `main(){` and `<? ` respectively.

Comment: @WanderNauta Bootstrapping code is the code that's essentiell to get a working noop program.

Comment: @TimWolla That definition won't fly. A zero-byte file is a working noop PHP script, for example.

Comment: @WanderNauta A zero byte file is a working noop in every language.

Comment: So what's bootstrapping code then? :)

Comment: for the limit I'd say [tag:code-shuffleboard] or [tag:restricted-source]

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to vote to delete this.

Answer (score 3):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

## Nonogram it

[Nonograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) are one of my favorite types of puzzles, but sometimes there are not enough of them to solve!

The challenge here is to write a program that would take an image and output the values for the columns and rows of the puzzle.

INPUT: black and white PNG on STDIN

OUTPUT: two lines with the values to create the puzzle. First line is the columns, second the rows. The format of both lines is: `[a,b,c...],[d,...],...`  (lists of integers separated with commas delimited with `[]`, with each list separated by commas, ending in a newline. No dangling commas allowed inside the lists or at line end)

The squares on the image should be of 5x5px. The thereshold for determining if a square is filled is if it has at least 30% black inside it.

(3 sample images will be added later)

---

I'm not sure about the scoring for this challenge, most likely it should be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Additional scoring criteria I can think of:

- allowing to enter square size or cols*rows of the puzzle.
- accepting non black and white images
- reading other image types
- providing a solver

Comment: wait, is the PNG itself in the STDIN, or a file path to it? I assume the latter, but it's currently formulated as if it's the former. Also, the threshold needs to be clarified. Also, why is the image scaled up in the first place?

Comment: Also, I'd prefer an ascii-art input (a grid of hashes and spaces) than having the challenge complicated by looking up and interfacing an image manipulation API.

Comment: It could be a file path if that's more accesible.
I didn't say the image was scaled, the 5*5 squares are for the grid to create the nonogram, just to avoid another required parameter(number of cols*rows desired).
About the ascii-art, that would have no challenge, just a count()

Comment: I don't think a PNG library showoff is a good challenge for this site. There's no thinking present, just having to learn an API and hope it has short enough names.

Comment: I don't understand the 5x5 rule. Is it that there are 5x5 pixels in the image, and 5x5 pixels in the grid? 5x5s are no puzzles.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first challenge using PNG, so I see no problem there.
About the grid, I'll prepare the example images later, I hope that'll be clearer to understand

Comment: Seeing that you prescribe exactly how black and white cells are to be determined, unique solubility of the resulting nonogram is no criterion?

Comment: @m.buettner I proposed the fixed grid and cell criterion with the idea of being able to check results against others. 
I forgot about ambiguous solutions, and I don't know how difficult is to test for it, specially if it ends as a code-golf. Maybe I should rule it out explicitly to keep answers simpler?

Comment: @Einacio well, uniqueness could be checked with a solver (there might be easier ways). I suppose you just have to decide whether you want soluble or comparable answers. If you are going for soluble, you can make this a "code challenge" and determine the score based on both code length and similarity to input image.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: @programmer5000 Hi, I totally forgot about this challenge, I haven't had much free time in those 3 years to give it some love. I would be delighted to see someone pull it through, do I have to do something more than post it in the chat?

Comment: @Einacio just post [a link to this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1342/58826) and nothing else in that chat room.

Answer (score 3):

*Hi, first time golf questioner, hopefully I'm doing it right!*

## Maths Trade Calculator

A **maths trade** (or "math" trade if you prefer) is a way of calculating complex trades of arbitrary items in a circle of participants where not all participants want all items.

X participants have an item they would like to trade. Each participant is assigned a unique number, and provides a list of (numbers identifying) the items they would willingly trade their item for. They may provide an empty list (i.e. they would rather not trade).

### Input

X lines, one for each participant, comprising a unique number identifying them, followed by a colon, then a comma-separated-list of numbers identifying other items that they would trade for. e.g.:

```
1:2,3,4
2:
3:1,4
4:2
```

The numbers identifying the participants will not necessary be in order, nor will they necessarily be 1 to X. You may assume that they will be numeric.

This string can be in STDIN, or an argument to a function, or similar and can be followed by a new-line or not, whatever the coder prefers.

### Output

One or more trade loops in which all participants are making trades they're happy with. Each loop should be on a new line and comprise a participant number, followed by "->", followed by the participant they should give their item to, then another "->", and another participant number etc, until the loop is closed and the last participant number matches the first one. Another line is added with the number of completed trades. e.g.:

```
1->3->1
2
```

Participants for which no valid trade is possible are omitted.

Output can be via STDOUT, or returned as a string, or something else, with an optional final new-line.

### Trade rules

1. A participant may not be involved in more than one trade
2. A participant may not receive an item that they didn't want
3. All loops must be closed
4. Maximum number of possible trades should be completed (i.e. no submitting a zero-trade output and claiming it's valid). If there are multiple permutations, pick whichever you prefer.

This is a **code golf** challenge, so shortest working code wins.

#### Some more example inputs and possible outputs

#### 1

```
1:2,3,4,5
2:3,5,7,9
3:1,2,5,6,10
4:
5:1,2,3,4,10
6:5,7,9
7:3,6,9,10
8:1,2,4,10
9:1
10:9

1->9->10->3->1
7->2->5->6->7
8
```

For instance, in this trade: 9 stated that he would accept 1's item in a trade, 10 stated that he would accept 9's item, 3 would accept 10's and 1 would accept 3's. In the second loop, 2 receives 7's item, 5 receives 2's, 6 receives 5 and 7 receives 6's. (Other outputs are possible from this input.)

#### 2

```
1:2
4:
2:3
5:1
3:4

0
```

#### 3

```
1:5,9
5:1
9:1

1->5->1
2
```

`1->9->1` is also valid in this case, but both cannot be completed. Either is acceptable.

*Thanks for reading guys! Let me know if there are any improvements I can make.*

Comment: *"can be followed by a new-line or not, whatever the coder prefers."* How flexible is this? For instance, can I use trailing commas, like `1:2,4,7,` if it makes my code shorter?

Comment: Will the participants always be numbered `1` to `n` and their input lines provided in order? If so, state it. If not, include a test case which fails if an implementation decides to ignore everything before the `:` in each input line.

Comment: @m.buettner I would say a trailing comma is not acceptable, on the end of any line, or the end of the input/output.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good tip. I'll correct the question to state that you can't assume that the numbers will be 1 to n, in order.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 3):

### Design and Solve a Maze

([this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/27057/design-and-solve-a-maze-on-hold-while-sandboxing) on hold while the details are ironed out)

---

Your task is to play the roles of **both** characters in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3-a58Wt2tk&t=41) from Inception. In it, Cobb gives Ariadne a challenge:

> You have two minutes to design a maze that takes one minute to solve.

Some liberties will be taken on that description. Most importantly, this challenge is not time-based, rather scores are based on the effectiveness of your mazes and maze-solvers.

*I apologize for the many edits to this challenge as we iterate towards an easy and fair format..*

#### Part I: Maze format

All mazes are square. A cell in the maze is represented as a zero-indexed tuple `row column`.

Walls are represented by two binary strings: one for horizontal walls (which block movement between rows) and vertical walls (vice versa). On an `NxN` maze, there are `Nx(N-1)` possible walls of each type. Let's take a 3x3 example where the cells are labelled:

```
A   B | C
   ---
D | E   F
   ---
G   H | I
```

all possible vertical walls are: `AB BC DE EF GH HI`. Translated into a string, the walls shown are `011001` for vertical walls and `010010` for horizontal walls. Also, by "binary string" I mean "the characters '0' and '1'".

The full maze format is a string which contains, in this order:

- width
- start cell tuple
- end cell tuple
- horizontal walls
- vertical walls

For example, this maze:

```
   0 1 2 3 4
   _________
0 | |  E|  _|
1 |  _|_|_  |
2 |_ _ _  | |
3 |  _ _  | |
4 |____S|___|
start:(4,2)
end:(0,2)
```

is formatted to this:

```
5
4 2
0 2
00001011101110001100
10100110000100010010
```

#### Part II: The Architect

The Architect program creates the maze. It must play by the rules and provide a valid maze (one where a solution exists, and the end is not on top of the start).

**input via stdin:** Two positive integers:

```
size [random seed]
```

Where `size` will be in `[15, 50]`. You are encouraged to make use of the random seed so that matches can be replayed, although it is not required.

**output to stdout:** A valid size x size (square) maze using the format described in Part I. "valid" means that a solution exists, and the start cell is not equal to the end cell.

The score of an Architect on a given maze is

```
   # steps taken to solve
------------------------------
max(dist(start,end),(# walls))
```

So architects are rewarded for complex mazes, but penalized for each wall built (this is a substitute for Ariadne's time restriction). The `dist()` function ensures that a maze with no walls does not get an infinite score. The outside borders of the maze do not contribute to the wall count.

#### Part III: The Solver

The Solver attempts to solve mazes generated by others' architects. There is a sort of fog-of-war: only walls adjacent to visited cells are included (all others are replaced with '?')

**input via stdin:** the same maze format, but with '?' where walls are unknown, an extra line for the current location, and a comma-separated list of valid choices from this location. (This is a big edit that is meant to make it simpler to write a maze-parsing function)

example (same as the above 5x5 maze after taking one step left)

```
5
4 2
0 2
???????????????011??
????????????????001?
4 1
4 0,4 2
```

Which corresponds something like this, where `?` is fog:

```
   0 1 2 3 4
   _________
0 |????E????|
1 |?????????|
2 |?????????|
3 | ?_?_????|
4 |__C_S|_?_|
```

**output to stdout:** One of the tuples from the list of valid choices

Each Solver's score is the inverse of the Architect's score.

#### Part IV: King of the Hill

Architects and Solvers are given separate scores, so there could potentially be two winners.

Each pair of architects and solvers will have many chances to outwit each other. Scores will be averaged over all tests and opponents. Contrary to code golf conventions, highest average score wins!

I intend for this to be ongoing, but I can't guarantee continued testing forever! Let's say for now that a winner will be declared in one week.

#### Part V: Testing

I have written a Python testing kit which includes a Maze class for parsing and writing in the proper formats, as well as an example architect/solver pair: Daedalus and the Minotaur

Available on both [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72170447/codegolf/maze.zip) and [GitHub](http://github.com/wrongu/maze-challenge)

#### Part VI: Submitting

- I maintain veto power over all submissions - cleverness is encouraged, but not if it breaks the competition or my computer! (If I can't tell what your code does, I will probably veto it)
- Come up with a name for your Architect/Solver pair. Post your code along with instructions on how to run it.

Comment: I suppose input is via STDIN? You might want to mention that explicitly, because at least the architect could just as well take the input via command-line arguments.

Comment: updated. I have a driver/referee program which will handle I/O; I'll update it to use stdin/stdout since that will no doubt be the easiest standard.

Comment: @m.buettner before de-sandboxing this, would you be willing to try the test kit?

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm afraid I'm too busy this week. Try ask for help in the chatroom.

Comment: Possible architect issue: With this scoring method (steps/walls), you can get a *minimum* score of `3` by simply putting the start/finish right next to each other with a single wall between. It takes three steps to go around. Most *actual* mazes I've seen have too many walls to make a score of `3` likely, much less guaranteed.

Comment: Thats a problem. What if the dist function was shortest path? Then only mazes which cause detours could get a score > 1

Comment: That would probably be better. That way it's scored on best vs actual. It *would* take away the incentive to figure out how to build hard mazes with few walls, though, which was interesting itself.

Comment: Hey rangu... not sure if you're still planning to do this thing, but overactor just said something in chat which reminded me of your challenge and might be a neat way to avoid the combined score: split this up into two code-challenges, one for maze generation and one for maze solving. Each code-challenge's benchmark set (to determine the scores) would be the outputs of the other challenge's participants. Then you could just pick a best solver and a best generator independently.

Answer (score 3):

## Help Joe Bloggs with his password hash

Joe was confidently using "password1" as his main password to all his accounts until one day he received an e-mail from fBay.
His account has been compromised and he must change his password immediately. Yet worse, the attacker had access to all Joe's accounts.
Being an engineer, Joe thought: *What if I could hash somehow my password using a keyword? I wouldn't need to remember any passwords and I would have a different one for each account.*

Joe then creates an algorithm - he takes the domain name as a key and creates the password for each of his account consisting of:

```
1. (<consonants><vowels>)(alternating case: lower, capital, lower...)
2. <number of consonants><number of vowels>
3. <sum of consonants and vowels numbers converted to a character on US Qwerty Keyboard>
```

Joe then opens an account on SO to create a new code golf challenge. He uses `stackoverflow` as a key to generate password:

```
1. sTcKvRfLwAoEo - consonants and vowels in alternating case
2. 94 - 9 consonants, 4 vowels
3. 9+4=13, 1+3=4, Shift+4=$
```

Therefore, Joe's password for stackoverflow is: `sTcKvRfLwAoEo94$`

#### Challenge

Create a shortest function to generate a password given the rules above. The code should accept a string type parameter `d` and return/display the generated password.

#### Rules

1. Only Latin letters from the input should be used. Any other characters should be ignored.
2. Minimum input length is 1 letter. (guys at q.com need passwords as well!)
3. Assume Y is a vowel
4. If vowels or consonants are missing, use `0` accordingly. E.g. input `a` would result in `a01!`
5. Shortest code wins

[List of vowels and consonants](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel)

[US qwerty keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @m.buettner. I meant to say, without using any libraries. The problem is, that people become lazy to think sometimes and just dive straight away to use [Linq](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28416/21491) where a bit of thought will [do](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28428/21491)

Comment: Well actually you can, I'm just checking now. You can do a lot of manipulations on strings without libraries.

Comment: Looping over string characters, concatenation work perfectly. Nevertheless, I've updated the challenge. If a function to depend on a library, it must be included in the character count.

Comment: 1. Strictly speaking, in .Net you don't *have* strings without libraries. The `string` keyword is syntactic sugar for a class in `mscorlib`. 2. As things currently stand, your rule 1 **strictly** prohibits something and then says what to do if you ignore that prohibition. This is illogical. It's also unclear what "*that*" in "*please inlcude that in characters count*" means. Does it mean that each submission should be a program as opposed to a code snippet? If so, state it explicitly.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know how to write it the best way. `mscorlib` is included by default so that is permissible. I don't want the code to use other libraries as `Linq` as it's less fun.

Comment: @m.buettner I agree with you. Nevertheless, there will solutions provided in other languages as well (there always are). And I would like the authors of those solutions to _think_ about the best approach in their language of choice without depending on libraries like `Linq`.

Comment: Does Rule 2 mean ONLY vowels/consonants to be used from input? What about symbols *@#$ etc. Depending on that answer, potentially clarify Rule 5 regarding symbol input.
As for Step 3 in the hash, should that progress further, similar to my Appended Numbers game so 103 consonants and 5 vowels would follow as 103+5 = 108, 1+0+8/10+8, etc.?

Comment: @Matt, clarified - only Latin letters are used from the input. If consonants or vowels are missing, use 0 instead. The sum should progress, until it's <=9. E.g. 103 consonants, 5 vowels: 103+5=108, 1+0+8=9. Then, Shift+9='('

Answer (score 3):

Author note: I was thinking about new genres today, and I had an idea. What if there could be a challenge that *encourages* people to write *good* code, instead of the code-golf gibberish we all know? Here's a challenge that attempts to do that. (This could even possibly be a [new-genre](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-genre), which would be great because it would bring in a greater high quality question volume to the site, but I'm terrible at coming up with names. Feel free to suggest something in the comments.)

---

## Build your own image editor

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [application-building](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-building) (?)

For this challenge, you will create the best GUI image editor that can perform the most tasks that you possibly can... from scratch.

### Tasks and scoring

Here are the features / tasks used to score your program. Each task is worth a certain amount of points, which is specified in brackets before the task description. For convenience, each task will also be prefixed by an ID string so that you can refer to them when describing your program.

- [1 A] Brush tool: Simple, click and drag the mouse to draw freestyle doodles. Must draw a contiguous path.

  - [1 A1] Ability to change the brush size.
- {TODO: etc., add more}

### Requirements

Your editor must conform to the following requirements:

- Must accept input via the mouse. Tools (brush, flood fill, etc.) can be switched and configured with keyboard shortcuts, by clicking icons with the mouse, through a menu, or however you would like.
- You may not use a single built-in function to accomplish one or more of the tasks. For example, if your language has a built-in image flood fill function, you may not use it and must build your flood fill from scratch.

### Final score and voting

This is the syntax you should use to describe your score in your answer:

```
# {language}, {your score} score
<sup>(features implemented: {A, A1, ...})</sup>

    {your code here}

{description, comments, other notes, etc. here}
```

The amount of votes your post has (upvotes minus downvotes) will be multiplied by {TODO: figure out a good number} and added to your score. (Do not add this to the score in your post, since votes change constantly; I will add them manually.) **Voters, please vote according to the following criteria:**

- elegance and readability of the source code
- ease of use of the image editor and how powerful it is
- remember to sort by "active" so that you're voting for new answers too, and not just the top voted ones!

Comment: [Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) A really good answer to this would run into millions of lines of code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, I was a little worried about that, but if it's not broad enough, it will be easy to just implement all the features. Any suggestions for fixing this? I was thinking of adding a "brevity" criterion in the voting section, but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Comment: To be honest, the site for *good* code is Code Review. They already have a monthly challenge, for which they post snippets for review. I don't see a need to copy them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Wait, isn't Code Review for questions and answers, not challenges and contests? In any case, is there any reason for that to prevent us from posting challenges like we always have?

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge . Surprised you don't know about it, given how dedicated you are to spying on them ;) In general, if a question is on topic for multiple stacks then there's no *obligation* to do the sensible thing and post it on the one which it best fits, but you should expect people to ask *why* you're not doing the sensible thing. I think you're going to have to work hard to turn this into a question which fits this site, whereas it's already a good fit for CR's challenge programme.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hmm, that's strange. Wouldn't that be more on-topic here? (And I only occasionally pop in to their chat/meta to see what they're up to. :-P)

Answer (score 3):

## Diplomacy

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

*Note for Sandbox:*
I have not finished (or really started) the control program for this game, because I wanted to see if there was interest in it before I dedicated too much time to the project. that means that the rule are still up to be tweaked, so please leave a comment if you have a suggestion, and comment or vote if you are interested in seeing this happen.

**Diplomacy** is a complex strategy game, with a very entertaining combat system. This challenge will be to write a bot to compete in a simplified version of diplomacy combat.

### Rules

#### Rounds

Countries (bots) will begin the game with 10 health, representing their remaining will to fight. The goal is to eliminate all other Nations by attacking them until they have 0 health.

The game will consist of several rounds.
On the first round, all bots will receive 2 numbers as command line arguments: The first will be the total number of countries fighting, and the second will be their number in the list. Each following round, bots will receive a command line arguments containing the actions taken by each player last round and a list of all bots and their remaining health separated by commas, like so

```
 1:A2,2:S3,3:A4,4:A3 1:10,2:7,3:7,4:1
```

Each bot must then output a desired action, which is one two commands

1. Attack a player. This is done by printing the letter A followed by the number of the player you with to attack. For instance, `A3`
2. Support a player. This will give the player you support a boosted attack.

#### Resolving combat

After player have sent in their moves, attack scores will be calculated thus:

1. All players start with a strength of 1, and one point is added for every player supporting them.  For instance, if the moves are `1:A3,2:S1,3:A2,4:S2` then bot 1 has strength 2, bot 2 has strength 2, bot three has strength 1, and bot 4 has strength 1.
2. After strength has been calculated, bots will deal damage based on their strength. The formula for damage is `(Attacker's strength + 1) - (Defender's Strength)` In the above situation, player 3 would take 2 damage and player 2 would take 0 damage. Note that, unlike regular diplomacy, attacking a supporter does not cut support.
3. All attack take place simultaneously and independently. This means that if player 1 and 2 both attack player 4, then they each deal 1 damage. If player 3 were to support player 4, then player 4 would take no damage.

#### Round Ends

After combat has been resolved, countries that have 0 health will no longer be able to attack or support. However, they still will be listed in the input with an health of 0. When a bot is eliminated, all remaining bots will receive a single point.

#### Ending the game

The game ends when either 100 turns have elapsed or only 2 or less players remain. At this point, the player with the highest remaining health is the winner and receives 1 point. In case of ties, all tied bots will revive 1 point. If all bots die on the same turn, this is not a tied victory, but mutually assured destruction, and all bots will receive 0 points.

#### Scoring

The control program will run 100 rounds of the game. The winner will be the country with the most points at the end of 100 rounds.

### Code

You may write in any language I can reasonably compile. I will make an effort to compile odd languages, but make no promises as to my ability to do so. Please provide your source code, an explanation, and a command line command to run your program.

Notes

- You are allowed to write to a file. In fact, you are encouraged to do so.
- Because this is a game where cooperation is paramount, you are allowed to write bots that work together, with the following restriction:

  - Only two bots can be written by a single player to work together at a time.
- Standard Loopholes apply. You are not allowed to change the way the control program runs. If you provide invalid input to the control program, the program will just skip your turn.
  However, you are allowed to spy on other countries files, and all bot programs will be in the same folder at runtime. This is war, after all!
- I reserve the right to disqualify any country that takes more than about a second to run, or that tries a loophole not mention within.   That being said, if it is sufficiently clever I will probably let it go.

I will have source code up soon for a sample country that will be competing, and will post the control program when I finish it.

Comment: "*In case of ties, all tied bots will revive 1 point*". Is that supposed to say "*receive*"? "*If all bots die on the same turn, ... all bots will receive 0 points.*" If there are two bots left, each of which has received 1 point from the earlier death of a third bot, and the two bots destroy each other on the same turn, what's the final score for the round? I'm not sure whether it's 0-0-0 or 1-1-0. "*You are allowed to write bots that work together*": but how can they identify each other? Do they have to use their moves as a covert channel?

Comment: "*Support a player. This will give the player you support a boosted attack.*" Or defence. Might be clearer to say "*boost that player's strength for the turn*". Should also state whether or not it's possible to support yourself.

Answer (score 3):

## Check GenericScript source code for compiler errors

Given the source code for a GenericScript program as input, parse the source code to check that it conforms to the syntax rules for the language. The syntax definition for GenericScript is below. If a part of the source code is found to be invalid, the program should output "Invalid syntax", otherwise it should output "Valid syntax".

**Win Criteria**

This is code golf. Shortest code wins.

**Syntax**

Source code will be considered to be valid if it matches the rule for "Program" below.

```
Program             = Sequence
Sequence            = Statement [Sequence]
Statement           = SequenceBlock | Assignment | If | While | Output
SequenceBlock       = "{" Sequence "}"
Assignment          = Identifier "=" (String | Bool); 
If                  = "if(" Bool ")" Statement ["else" Statement]
While               = "while(" Bool ")" Statement
Output              = "print(" String ");"
Identifier          = {Any sequence of alphanumeric characters prefixed with "var" }
Bool                = StringEquals | Identifier
StringEquals        = String "==" String
String              = StringConstant | OperatorConcat | Input | Identifier
StringConstant      = "'"StringContent"'"
StringContent       = Character [StringContent]
Character           = {Any character except for "'"}
OperatorConcat      = String "&" String
Input               = "read()"
```

Whitespace is defined as any sequence of the ascii characters 9, 10, 13 and 32. Whitespace characters are allowed between tokens but are not required.

**Rules**

1. The answer should be a complete program
2. [Standard input/output allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1326/21713)
3. [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny)
4. [Universally testable answers only](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2031/21713)

**Test Input**

Valid syntax:

```
print('What is your name?');
varInput = read();
print('Hello ' & varInput);
```

Invalid syntax:

```
if(read() == 'DoTask1')
  print('Executing you'r command');
```

Answer (score 3):

### Text Adventure Game

### Objective

Your goal is to develop a complete text-based adventure game with the shortest code possible.
The player navigates in a dungeon composed of rooms. The game objectives are to find the treasure, slain the dragon and rescue the princess.

### Rules

A room description is as follows:

```
You are in <description>.
You can go <exits>
You see <object>      (optional)
```

- **exits** can be "north", "east", "west", "south".
- **description** can be "a *adjective* cavern", "a *adjective* room", "a *adjective* corridor", "a *adjective* hall", "a cell",  "the dragon's lair".
- **adjective** can be "dark", "murky", "small", "large", "narrow", "gloomy", "huge", "strange", "tiny", "broad", "old".
- **object** can be "the princess", "the dragon", "a troll", "a goblin", "a sword", "gold", "a key", "a trunk".

Exit list must be comma-separated and end with "and". If there is no object in the room, the last line is omitted.

Example of valid description:

```
You are in a murky room.
You can go north, east and south.
You see a goblin.
```

The game accepts the following commands (case is ignored) :

- **GO direction** : *direction* can be NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH
- **TAKE item** : *item* can be SWORD, GOLD, KEY
- **KILL monster** : *monster* can be DRAGON, TROLL, GOBLIN. The DRAGON and the TROLL can be killed only if the user has the SWORD. If he hasn't, he loses the game. The weak GOBLIN can be killed with bare hands. When a monster dies, he disappears from the room. When the GOBLIN dies, he drops a SWORD. When the TROLL dies, he drops a KEY.
- **KISS person** : person can be PRINCESS, DRAGON, TROLL, GOBLIN. Kissing the princess validates one of the objective of the game, and the princess disappears from the room. Kissing a monster results in player death.
- **OPEN object** : object can be TRUNK. If the player has the KEY, the TRUNK object disappears and is replaced with GOLD.

**OBJECTS**
The player can perform an action on an object only if the object is in current room. A room can contain only one object ; a given object can be found in only one room. At the beginning of the game, only the following objects are placed in the map : PRINCESS, DRAGON, TROLL, GOBLIN, TRUNK. Other objects are not yet created.

**ACTIONS**

- If an action cannot be performed (e.g. GO NORTH where there is no exit to the north, or TAKE DRAGON, or DANCE GANGNAM STYLE), the message "Sorry, I can't do that" must be displayed.
- If an action can be performed, the message "OK" and the current room description should be displayed.
- You can read game commands from console or as a program parameter, as you wish.

**MAP**
The dungeon should have at least 30 rooms. The dungeon should not contains a series of more than 5 exits in the same direction. The exits between rooms must be consistent, e.g. if you go north from room #1 to room #2, there must a south exit in room #2 leading back to room #1.
Every room name should be unique. There must be at least one room of each kind (hall, cavern, corridor...)

- A hall has at least 3 exits.
- A corridor can have only 2 exits.
- The cell has only one exit.
- There is only one dragon's lair and only one cell, containing respectively the dragon and the princess.

**GAME END**
The game ends when the player has been killed, or when he has taken the gold, slain the dragon and kissed the princess.

- If the player dies, the message *"You have been killed by X !"* is displayed, with X being the name of the monster.
- If the player wins, the message *"Well done adventurer ! you've conquered the dungeon."* is displayed.

Player should not be able to win the game in less than 40 turns.

**Example**

```
You are in a murky room.
You can go north, east and south.
You see a goblin.
> KILL GOBLIN
Ok.
You are in a murky room.
You can go north, east and south.
You see a sword.
> TAKE SWORD
Ok.
You are in a murky room.
You can go north, east and south.
> GO NORTH
Ok.
You are in a narrow corridor.
You can go south and east.
```

### Scoring

*The shortest code wins.*

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your comments! I've updated the question.

Comment: Provided the player ignores the troll and goblin (i.e. doesn't try to kiss or kill them), they don't do anything?

Comment: @Peter you're right. Maybe the player should kill (with bare hands) the goblin in order to get the sword, and then kill the troll (with the sword) to get the key.

Comment: "The map must be spatially coherent" still doesn't disallow always going left without ending up in the same room twice, unless you specify that the rooms are all meant to be square (which is what I think you had in mind). Also, I still think that "at least" 30 rooms is unnecessary. Who would implement 8 additional rooms if they don't have to. It will definitely be shorter if I omit the two longest adjectives and just use all available combinations of the remaining ones (giving 30 unique rooms). So you can omit two adjectives and the "at least" right away, I'd say.

Comment: I think it's fine to keep "at least" there for flavour, same with additional adjectives. Also, someone *might* figure out a way to make the code shorter with a longer adjective (for that reason, having a few *more* adjectives might be nice)

Comment: @Martin I've added a criteria "Player should not be able to win in less than 30 turns", to force the golfer to implement more rooms.

Comment: @SuperChafouin That doesn't force it though. I just need to place the goblin at the end, troll at the beginning, trunk at the end, so that you need to traverse the map 3 times.

Comment: @Martin It's also here to prevent the dungeon to be too straightforward to solve, e.g. if all the objects are in 5 adjacent rooms near the player start location.

Comment: +1 for golfing in Inform 7.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: @programmer5000 Yes no problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Simulate a Quantum Circuit

**Work-in-progress** until I can make sure I know what I am doing and can finish the spec. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or maybe [advanced-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-code-golf)

---

Quantum computers are the way of the future!  Why wait, when you can simulate one now?

Your mission is to determine the output of a quantum circuit given its input and a diagram of logic gates.

## Details

You will simulate a single quantum register and apply a series of quantum logic gates to it.  A quantum register is a group of qubits.  The state of a register is described by a vector of `2^N` complex numbers, where `N` is the number of qubits in the register.

```
a|000>
b|001>
c|010>
d|011>
e|100>
f|101>
g|110>
h|111>
```

Above is a representation of a 3-qubit register.  Each letter (`a` `b` `c` etc.) represents a complex number. There is an addition restriction that:

```
|a|^2 + |b|^2 + |c|^2 + |d|^2 + |e|^2 + |f|^2 + |g|^2 + |h|^2 = 1
```

### Quantum gates

Gates are represented by a `2^N x 2^N` square unitary matrix, where `N` is the number of input qubits.  All quantum gates have the same number of outputs and inputs, since they neither create nor destroy qubits, they modify them.

A common quantum gate is called the Hadamard gate and acts on a single qubit.  The matrix `[H]` looks like this:

```
1/Sqrt(2)  1/Sqrt(2)
1/Sqrt(2)  -1/Sqrt(2)
```

If we let `[R]` represent the following 1-qubit register:

```
0.6|0>
O.8|1>
```

Then the application of the gate is represented by `[H][R]` and gives the following result:

```
7*Sqrt(2)/10|0>
 -Sqrt(2)/10|1>
```

It is still true that the sum of the squares of the absolute values is equal to 1.

**(TODO: explain how to apply gates to larger registers)**

### Measurement

Measurement collapses the state of the quantum register.

**(Todo: Explain how measurement works)**

## Input

## Output

Answer (score 3):

## BS

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

The goal of this challenge is to implement an AI for the game of BS, also known as Bull Shit, Cheat, Bluff, and numerous other names.

The game is outlined in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_(game)).

## The Rules of the Game

For the purposes of this challenge, the game will work like this:

1. A standard 52-card deck is dealt out to the players
2. The current rank is set to Ace
3. The play order is randomized
4. The player holding the Ace of Hearts goes first
5. On each player's turn:

   1. The current player plays some number of cards
   2. The current player states how many of what rank they played
   3. Other players may declare 'BS'.
   4. If any player declares 'BS':

      1. All players are notified of which players declared 'BS'.
      2. The played cards are revealed to all players.
      3. If the played cards are **inconsistent** with the current player's statement:

         - The current player adds the played cards and all cards in the pile to their hand
      4. If the played cards are **consistant** with the current player's statement:

         - The **last** player to declare 'BS' that round adds the played cards and pile to their hand.
   5. If no player declares 'BS':

      1. The played cards are added to the pile, without revealing them.
      2. If the played cards were inconsistant with the current player's statement, the current player may declare 'Peanut Butter'.
   6. If the current player has no cards in their hand, the current player wins.
   7. The current rank is incremented. (If the current rank is King, it becomes Ace.)

## The Messaging Protocol

Play will be conducted via messages passed to the standard input and received from the standard output of each program. Each message will be terminated with a single newline character.

### Cards

Card ranks are represented as one of `A`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `T`, `J`, `Q`, or `K`. Card suits will be represented as one of  `S`, `C`, `H`, or `D`.
Cards are represented as the rank, followed immediately by a suit. For instance, the Ten of Clubs would be represented by `TC`, and the Three of Hearts would be represented by `3H`.

A hand of cards will be represented as a space-delimited sequence of cards. For instance, a hand containing the Queen of Spades and the Six of Diamonds could be represented as `QS 6D` or `6D QS`.

### Player Identification

A player will be represented by their nickname, followed by a number from 0 to 32768, in parenthesis, formatted as an integer. This number is guaranteed to be unique within a particular game. A player's nickname must have at least one character, can have up to 32 characters, and may only include letters, numbers, and underscores. For instance, a player with nickname `ExampleAI` and ID number 16480 would be identified in the game as `ExampleAI(16480)`.

When the game begins, each program will recieve a message containing their unique ID:

```
Unique ID: uniqueID
```

Each player will reply with their desired nickname:

```
Nickname: name
```

Names may contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores.

After all players have responded with their nickname, the standard play sequence begins.

### Standard Play Sequence

When a player's turn begins, each player will receive a  be given a list of the players and their card counts, in order of play:

```
Players: player[count], player[count], ... player[count]
```

Each player will be informed of the contents of their hands:

```
Hand: initial_hand
```

The current the player will then receive this message:

```
Your turn: current_rank
```

The current player will reply with a space-separated list of  of cards:

```
Play: list_of_cards
```

Once they have submitted their play, all players will receive the number of cards, formatted as an integer, along with the current rank:

```
Player player plays: nunber_of_cards x current_rank
```

Each other player may then declare BS on that play by sending any message up to 32 characters, containing the capital letters `B` and `S`, and otherwise only contains lowercase letters and spaces. So any of `Bull Shit`,  `Bananna Split` or `Bacon Sandwich` would be acceptable.

During this period, the current player may declare Peanut Butter by sending any message up to 32 characters, as long as it contains the capital letters `P` and `B`, and otherwise only contains lowercase letters and spaces. So any of `Peanut Butter`, `Pancake Batter` or `Polish Bacon` would be acceptable.

In order to allow the game to move faster, if a player does not wish to declare either of these things, they must instead send:

```
Pass
```

After all players have responded, all players will receive a list of players who called BS, in the order they called it:

```
Called BS: player, player ... player
```

If no player called BS, this message will still be sent --- it just won't have any players listed.
If any player did call BS, then all players will recieve:

```
Player player had played: list_of_cards
```

If they were bluffing, all players recieve:

```
Player player was bluffing.
```

And the current player receives:

```
Your bluff was called: list_of_cards_recieved
```

If they were not bluffing, all players recieve:

```
Player player was not bluffing.
```

```
Player last_player receives the pile.
```

The last player who called BS recieves this message:

```
You misjudged: list_of_cards_received
```

The list of cards received will contain, in reverse chronological order, the contents of each play since the last call. (Separate plays will not be delimited in the list.)

If no player declared BS, and the current player was bluffing and declared Peanut Butter, then all players recieve the message:

```
Player player was bluffing.
```

If the current player has no cards left in their hand, all players receive this message, and the game terminates:

```
Player player won!
```

Otherwise, the next player's turn begins.

---

## Example Game

The following might be considered a typical (abbreviated) message transcript:

```
Unique ID: 16481
> Nickname: Alice
Players: Alice(16481)[18], Bob(16479)[17], Charlie(16480)[17]
Hand: 2D 7S AS TC 5S JS JC 3C 8H 9D 5D AH 7C 6C 4D KC KH KS
Your turn: A
> Play: AS 2D AH
Player Alice(16481) plays: 3 x A
> PB
Called BS:
Player Alice(16481) was bluffing.
Players: Bob(16479)[17], Charlie(16480)[17], Alice(16481)[15]
Hand: 7S TC 5S JS JC 3C 8H 9D 5D 7C 6C 4D KC KH KS
Player Bob(16479) plays: 2 x 2
> BS
Called BS: Alice(16481)
Player Bob(16479) had played: 2H 2C
Player Bob(16479) was not bluffing.
Player Alice(16481) takes the pile.
You misjudged: 2H 2C AS 2D AH
Players: Charlie(16480)[17], Alice(16481)[20], Bob(16479)[15]
Hand: 7S TC 5S JS JC 3C 8H 9D 5D 7C 6C 4D KC KH KS 2H 2C AS 2D AH
 .
 .
 .
Players: Alice(16481)[3], Bob(16479)[41], Charlie(16480)[8]
Hand: KC KH KS
Your turn: K
> Play: KC KH KS
Called BS: Charlie(16480), Bob(16479)
Player Alice(16481) was not bluffing.
Player Bob(16479) receives the pile.
Player Alice(16481) won!
```

Your implementation may be written in any language, provided that you, upon request, provide a link to a suitable free-as-in-freedom compiler or interpreter that I can download and run at no cost. You also need to provide a UNIX command that can start your program.

## Sandbox Questions

I want to gauge the community's interest in my problem before finalizing the spec and writing the control program.

I also need to get some idea of what sort of time-limiting scheme would be reasonable. In order to be able to to a lot of runs, I will need to be able to ensure that each AI doesn't take too much time to make its decisions, or prevent a stuck AI from holding up a game. I also need to be able to ensure that there is no motivation to deliberately stall a game. For example, if an AI determines that it is very unlikely to win, it might stall in order to prevent the game from finishing.

I would also like feedback on the messaging protocol:

- Are there any additional messages that you think should be passed?
- Would it be more convenient/clear if one or more of them were formatted differently?

  - Would it be better to use a different format for the  `plays` message?
  - Would it be better to use different words to help distinguish the `plays` and `played` messages?

Comment: It looks like quite a tough challenge, but should be enjoyable!

Comment: @PopeyGilbert By the way, there was one thing I accidentally left out that I need feedback on. Specifically, time limits - to deal with intentional stalling, getting stuck, or taking too long to decide.

Comment: A question and a feedback. Does our program run as "stop and run" or must receive feedback continuously? And for feedback. I honestly think that the whole `username` things is kinda confusing. Maybe if you just use only unique id? (Like just simple 0,1,2,3 instead of username)

Comment: Oh! More things! I also realize that suit doesn't really matter, right? (We only use suit for deciding who goes first), so fmpov, you can ditch the communication protocol for the suit. (No need for `S`,`C`,`D`,`H`) We can just use simple `random` from the computer. Question: What will happened if everybody make infinity loop of `pass`. For time limit, I prefer 1 second. If no response, make it auto `pass`. (KOTH chess time limit is 2 seconds. That's why 1 second is good enough)

Comment: @Realdeo Card suit is also used to distinguish between separate instances of a card. If Alice plays 3x2 (2S 2D 2C), is not revealed, and Bob gets the pile later, and then Bob plays 3x2 (2S 2C 2H), and this is revealed, it is important for Alice that she knows all four Twoes have passed through Bob's hand. There are other ways that can be used as well.

Comment: @Realdeo I am not sure what you mean by "Does our program run as "stop and run" or must receive feedback continuously?". If you mean, "Does an AI program halt in the periods where no response is expected from it?" the answer is no.

Comment: @Realdeo If everybody makes an infinity loop of `pass`, then eventually someone will run out of cards, since you are required to play at least one card each turn.

Comment: @Realdeo Which is why making a automatic `pass` after a timeout not work when waiting for a player to decide their play. Perhaps a simple rule like 'if you take more than 1 second to decide what to play, four cards are selected at random from your hand'.

Comment: And if a player has less then 4 cards? I think in some AI website, like aigames.com, they're like forced to give up that hand? You really want to test your entry before put them in the arena(like vsing a bot dummy?) Either way, this is a good challenge =)

Comment: @Realdeo Also note that you can actually play more than four cards in one play. A case where you might wish to do this is when: the next player is very close to winning _and_ some other player is close to winning _and_ you believe(all opponents believe(your next opponent will bluff) _and_ the next opponent will not bluff _and_ the next opponent believes(the other opponent close to winning will call BS against them)). A little convoluted, but could happen.

Comment: @Realdeo Just to explain what I mean, is that there are two people close to winning, each of which would like to dump a large stack of cards on top of the other. Because of this, they both let your obvious bluff slide because they believe that will let them dump a large stack on the other.

Comment: Don't worry I understand. This is a really famous high school game in my country. It just... a little bit too complex for CR. When I saw chess KOTH, I was kinda pessimist. This one? This may deserve it's own AI website. #seriously. I'm just trying to simplify this game =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16951/discussion-between-ajmansfield-and-realdeo).

Comment: RE the messaging service, I think the other players should be able to see how many cards the other players have. Also, card counting should be prohibited because that would make the game too easy.

Comment: @BetaDecay First off, according to the protocol, every player is informed of every other player's hand size at the beginning of every round.

Comment: @BetaDecay  Secondly, card counting is the _whole point_ of BS. That aspect of the game -- attempting to keep track who has what cards, estimating hand contents based on unconfirmed plays, etc -- _is_ the game. Playing strategies are comparatively trivial to bluff-calling strategies.

Comment: Yes, but a computer can card count extremely well whilst the fun in BS is due to how hard it is to card count.

Comment: @BetaDecay Card counting in BS is a lot harder than you might think. While you can keep track of who picked up the cards you played, etc, the moment they play anything, you no longer can tell with any certainty where those cards are. Did they play what they said they did? If not, was it the cards you gave them, or something else? Taking this farther, a really advanced AI might try to estimate what _other_ players know abut card locations, or even what other players know about what other players know about card locations.

Comment: @Beta Decay also I think the fun in BS (as played in most groups) is the fact that most decisions are based on reading facial expressions and stuff, which isn't possible for AIs to do to each other. That, and the fact that most people aren't actually any good, making winning only slightly more than luck.

Comment: That's a good point about the facial expressions

Answer (score 3):

### Turn my keyboard into a piano [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

I'm sure we've all thought "man, wouldn't it be cool if my keyboard played musical notes as I program?". Of course, the answer to that question is a resounding ***no***.

Regardless, it's what you're going to make.

### Input

Input will be given, in real-time, on the keyboard.

The keyboard mapping that you will use is given in the diagram below. This kind of layout is used by several music programs already.

[image: A keyboard layout, with notes assigned to several of the keys.]

You can see that the bottom row (`Z, X, C, V, B... ., /`) represents all of the white keys, and the black keys are added on the row above (`S, D, G, H, J... L, ;`). This is then repeated on the two rows above, except the notes are an octave higher.

The notes C5 to E5 are repeated both on the lower rows and the upper rows.

So, if the user were to input `Q` (or `,`) on the keyboard, middle-C (C5) should play. Similarly, if they input `B`,  G4 should play.

<sup>The diagram above is an edited form of an image found [here](http://sonantlive.bitsnbites.eu/).</sup>

### Output

The only output will be sound. The actual sound used is up to you (it could be a piano sample or the internal beeper), but it should output sound at the correct pitch.

The program should not terminate by itself - the user should be able to keep inputting notes until they get bored.

### References

- A diagram of the US keyboard layout (for comparison with the image above) can be found [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg/900px-KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg.png).
- A table of the frequencies of notes can be found [here](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html). The range of notes that you will be using are from C4 to E6, inclusive.

### Rules and Disambiguation

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest correct implementation wins.
- Input should be given in real-time (i.e. no pressing Enter between each inputted note).

  - There should be no greater than a 0.25 second delay between pressing a key and hearing the note.
- Only programs that have the notes correctly mapped to the QWERTY keyboard will be accepted.
- The only output should be sound. There should be nothing displayed (except for a mandatory console window or similar).
- Polyphony (multiple notes playing at once) is not part of the specification.
- The program should not terminate by itself - a user should be able to keep pressing keys and hearing notes until they decide to close it.
- The waveform outputted is not important (it can be a beep or a piano sound or whatever you like); the pitch, however, should be accurate.

  - The file size of any sound files used will not be counted in the bytecount.
  - Please link any sound files you use with your answer.

### Meta

- There are probably some obvious things that I've forgot to explain - please point these out!
- Also let me know if any of the wording is confusing.
- I've assumed that the readers will at least know very basic music theory (e.g. that there are 12 semitones in an octave). Is this okay?
- "Polyphony is not part of the specification" - polyphony is not the focus of the program, and therefore shouldn't be a consideration when submitting answers (i.e. if the shortest implementation means that one note will stop when a new note is played, then that's fine). Is this acceptable?
- Should I exclude the use of any external libraries that are designed to play sound or designed to repeat a function at regular intervals? Should I count sound file size in the score? I'm worried that having either of these would limit the possible entries to those that can use the internal beep (so, C/C++, C#, Python, Java?...).
- Another problem may be portability, or the lack thereof (e.g. C/C++ using the Windows API to access the `Beep()` function).

<sub>Really meta: answers/edits by me won't be done until the morning (approximately 9 hours from now).</sub>

Comment: Does sound need to continue until `key_up`, or is just a short "beep" okay no matter how long the key is pressed?

Comment: *"Of course....resounding no.... regardless.."* why shit on your own question? Change it to a slightly ironic *"Of course we have! Well, that's what you're going to make"*

Comment: 1,2 The wording is mostly OK Regarding @Geobits point, I think a short beep has to be acceptable. One must delve deep into API to know when a key is released (if the hardware tells at all.) Make the US keyboard requirement clearer. Take the linked image of a US keyboard, mark note names on it in color and include it in the question (I may do it for you.) Without having both on the same diagram, I found it hard to work out which notes on my Spanish keyboard end up in odd places. 3. Theory is very basic here, no need to explain Maybe link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation

Comment: Allow libraries for sound functions. Otherwise it'll definitely be won by a language with builtins. Portability is always an issue with sound, but on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25242/15599 the OP did get my Windows answer working on his Linux machine after many comments. Avoid polyphony. Computer & phone keyboard matrixes can't handle it properly. If you press 1,3,7,9 on a numeric keypad and release 1, the release can't be detected because there's still an electric path through the other keys. Real music keyboards have a diode on every key, or individual wires, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Hi, @steveverrill, thanks for your comments. I haven't really been very interested in PCCG recently so I haven't been replying/making changes. Thanks for the suggestions - I'll review the post sometime soon.

Comment: If this is code-golf, then I suggest that you choose a set sound to make it fair for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

## Irreducible Polynomials over a Finite Field

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra)[polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

Given a polynomial whose coefficients are in a finite field, deduce whether or not it is irreducible, without using any related built-ins (you can use a built-in that represents polynomials, but you cannot use built-ins for factoring or otherwise finding information about the polynomial).

A polynomial in `F[x]` (where `F` is a field) is considered [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) if it cannot be factored into the product of non-constant polynomials.

### I/O:

Your program/function will take two inputs:

- a prime number for the order of the Finite Field
- some representation for the polynomial

Output a truthy value if the polynomial is irreducible, and a falsy value otherwise.

### Test Cases

Your program **must** run in a reasonable time for this (i.e. 1 hour is definitely too long):

```
>>> F = 2, f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
false
>>> F = 5, f(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 + x
false
>>> F = 2, f(x) = x^4 + x + 1
true
>>> F = 5, f(x) = x^3 + x + 1
true
>>> F = 5, f(x) = x^6 + 2x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1
false
>>> F = 2, f(x) = x^6 + x^2 + 1
false
>>> F = 5, f(x) = 4x^4
false
```

## Meta Note:

These are all really related:

- [Prime polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48037/9498)
- [Factor a polynomial over a finite field or the integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38513/9498)
- [Irreducible polynomials over GF(5)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69608/9498)

The first especially. This challenge is very similar to the first, except that the first is for irreducible polynomials over `Z` (the integers), whereas this is for irreducible polynomials over finite fields. Although the challenges are similar, I feel this is different enough to warrant a new challenge

Comment: Is the polynomial guaranteed to be monic? Is the zero polynomial irreducible? Also, are you OK with brute-force solutions that take huge amounts of time?

Comment: @xnor No, the polynomial is not guaranteed to be monic, yes brute-force is okay if it runs in reasonable time for the test cases - I wrote a program that took <20 min for all but the 2nd last test case, which would take 2 days. Regarding zero polynomial, I need to do a bit of research first.

Comment: Now that I almost have an answer to the polynomial factoring question I can say that the test cases can be handled by brute force in a slow language in a few seconds. It's the case over Z that allows tough performance requirements with simple test cases.

Comment: @programmer5000 No, I would still like to use this. I had forgotten about it, and I will improve it and post it to main. Thank you for reminding me about this post

Comment: I feel like many people will not know what a finite field is. I think you should explain it in the post to allow people to answer without google.

Answer (score 3):

#### Stitch a Picture

A few weeks ago, I asked [Stitch a picture](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture).  Since then:

- The question has received several upvotes and no downvotes - hopefully an indication that the community thinks this is as interesting as I do
- No complete answers
- Several interesting comments - in particular [this one from @bazzargh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture#comment92775_38534)

In short it looks like this question is a lot harder than I though it would be.  It turns out from @bazzargh's comment that I have stumbled into an area of current research, and that perfect solutions are not so easily attainable as I had assumed.

With that in mind, I think its time I took this back to the sandbox to make this into the decent question that I think the subject deserves - and I think I need some community help with that.

I am posting several possibilities I am considering as comments.  Vote for these comments as you feel appropriate, and/or add your own suggestions.

---

I'm going to Yosemite this weekend (woohoo!) so will probably pick this up again next week.

#### Update

I have relinquished control of this question by putting it in [Secret Santa's Sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7805/11259)

Comment: [@Will pointed out](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture#comment89435_38534) that padding the original picture with black boundaries possibly makes the problem harder.  Instead we can have the original picture be cropped down to the nearest 100x100 pixel multiple and not worry about black boundaries at all

Comment: [@MartinBüttner suggested](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture#comment91388_38534) turning this into a [tag:code-challenge] and scoring based on the number of correctly placed tiles.  Given that perfect solutions appear to be hard to come by in general, this is probably a better scoring criteria

Comment: Briefly reviewing [the paper cited in @bazzargh's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture#comment92775_38534) I see that my problem is even more complex, in that the tiles are also randomly rotated.  Since this is complicating the problem beyond current research, I think it would be good to remove the rotation part completely.

Comment: Note that I didn't suggest scoring by correctly placed tiles but by correctly aligned edges. That's a huge difference, and in your version you could basically correctly assemble almost the entire picture, but still get 0 score if the chunk you've assembled correctly is off by a tile (since there's no indication where it goes unless you manage to get W tiles next to or H tiles on top of each other.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, that is a better idea.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I suggest only allowing translation (no rotation) of the tiles, which simplifies it somewhat, but I suspect still difficult enough to be a challenge.

Comment: Taken https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12421#12421

Answer (score 3):

## Let's talk about this...

I am planning on hosting a King of the Hill challenge in which bots will have to coordinate each other in order to be successful. The idea is to play a Diplomacy-like game between bots. The engine (still in development) will start the bots and communicate with them via stdin/stdout. There will be three phases:

**0. Initialization**

Well, this is not a recurring phase, it is just the engine telling each bot his id, the total number of bots participating and a seed, which can be used for generation of pseudo-random numbers (bots need to be deterministic).

**1. Talking Phase (10s)**

In the Talking phase, bots can send messages to each other (via engine) in order to coordinate their actions. To this end, a common language is necessary. This language should be able to express any ideas, plans and opinions a bot could have. However, not every bot is forced to be able to understand everything. Simpler bots might just ignore messages they do not understand.

Since I would like each player to be able to submit more than one bot, it is forbidden to implement a "secret handshake" by which bots recognize each other and from then on work together unconditionally.

**2. Planning Phase (2s)**

In this phase, bots submit what they want to do this turn. Each bot has a certain amount of supply (initially five), and can command one action per supply point. There are three possible actions:

1. Attack another bot
2. Support another bot's attack against a third bot
3. Defend another bot

There are some restrictions:

- Per opponent, you can *either* attack or defend them, and only once
- You cannot support an attack against a bot you also defend
- You cannot attack, defend, support yourself or a dead bot, and neither can you support attacks against yourself

**3. Resolution Phase (as short as possible)**

After all orders have been submitted, the engine will resolve them simultaneously in the following way:

The *defending strength* of each bot is the number of bots defending that bot.
The *attacking strength* of each attack is the number of support orders for that attack.
Each attack with an attacking strength greater than the defending strength of the attacked bot results in the supply counter of the attacked bot being reduced by one, and the supply counter of the attacker being increased by one.

Support orders which support a non-existent attack do nothing.

Then, all bots with supply of zero or less will be shut down by the engine: they died.

Afterwards, all remaining bots are informed about the decisions of other bots, and a new turn begins with its Talking Phase.

**Further Rules**

A game will consist of ten plus random number turns, so that "last turn betrayals" are not possible. The supply count of each bot will count towards their total score. I plan an ensemble of about 100 games. The bot with the highest total score wins. Tie-breaker will be the popularity (number of votes).

I am interested in your opinion: do you think that this challenge is too complex? I imagine that the code of a decent bot would be too long to fit in a post. So people would have to use github or pastebin or similar to submit their entries. The main problem imo is the interpretation of the (yet to be determined) common language.

Comment: I like it a lot. One possible variation would be to make the "secret handshakes" a feature. To do this, you could allow multiple instances of the same bot. Then part of the challenge is to recognise your own kin and mutually support them; and a viable strategy is to try and work out other players' secret handshakes and imitate them. If you're ok with emphasising this aspect of it, then you can make the shared language pretty unrestricted, e.g. bots can just send arbitrary strings to each other. (I realise this is not what you have in mind, I just thought I'd mention the idea.)

Comment: @Nathaniel, what you propose is a battle of obfuscation/cryptography. What I would like to see is a battle of diplomacy.

Comment: Fair enough - I just thought I'd say it in case it sparked any interesting thoughts for you, but I knew it was probably too different from what you want to see. If I have any other ideas about your challenge I'll let you know. Designing the language really seems to be the hard part.

Comment: A diplomatic KOTH is something I've been wanting to see for a while.  Working out the specifics of the "diplomatic language" is going to be the most difficult part.  My proposal is that each message can either 1) state an intention to another bot, or 2) request an action from another bot.  Each message would be formatted in a way similar to how a final command would be.

Comment: @PhiNotPhi: Thanks for the Feedback! I also imagined something similar with the ability to link atomic statements in a boolean fashion.

Answer (score 3):

## Find the Minimum Width of a Set of Points

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[time-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity)

Given a set of points in 2D space, you're to find the direction along which those points occupy the shortest width.

More formally, consider a set of *n* points *P = {p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>n</sub>}*, where *p<sub>i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>)*, and a unit vector ***d*** = (x<sub>d</sub>, y<sub>d</sub>). Now *K* is the set of lengths obtained from [orthogonal projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) of *P* onto **d**. In particular, *k<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub>x<sub>d</sub> + y<sub>i</sub>y<sub>d</sub>*. The **width** *L* of *P* along **d** is defined as *max k<sub>i</sub> - min k<sub>i</sub>*. Your task is to find the **d** along which *L* is minimal.

To keep things interesting, your algorithm's time complexity must not exceed *O(n log n)*.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN, command-line argument or function argument. The result may be printed to STDOUT or returned.

You can expect the input *P* to be in any convenient list or string format, but the input must not be pre-processed (e.g. sorted by coordinates). You may assume that the input contains at least 2 points and that no two points coincide.

The output must be correct to 10 significant (decimal) digits. Of course, **d** is only unique up to the relative sign of the coordinates, so there are two correct answers for each input. You may return either of those.

You must not use built-in functions related to this problem, like finding the minimum width of a polygon, or computing the convex hull of a set of points. You *may* use built-in vector/matrix types and operations.

### Sandbox Notes

- I'll write my own solution at some point next week, and use it to provide a number of test cases.
- I'm also planning to add a handful of diagrams to clarify the definitions.
- The challenge was inspired [by this proposal from Calvin's Hobbies](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2171/8478), I think they are sufficiently different, as this problem here is only one approach to tackling his challenge (and even then it's only a subproblem). But if people think, they are too similar, and posting this one would make his a duplicate in the future, I'll retract this challenge (as I'd really like to see his posted some time).

Comment: I hope you're still planning on posting this. Just a few notes: (a) The minimal direction is not generally unique (e.g., if we have a regular polygon, or just a single point). You'd might want to make the actual (scalar) width the output instead. (b) I assume the input is never empty? (c) Can it contain duplicates?

Comment: @Ell yes I still want to post this. Just didn't get around to writing the reference yet. a) good point. I'll think about asking for the width vs asking for any minimal direction. b) yes, will clarify. c) I'll think about that. Probably not.

Answer (score 3):

## Happy Holidays!

### Introduction

With the holidays upon us, I decided to make an appropriately themed challenge. You are provided with a list of holidays and their respective date ranges, and given a date, you have to output a holiday greeting or the time remaining until the next holiday as appropriate.

### Challenge

The list of holidays is below. You have to include it in your program (so no using a library or other external resource for this). Feel free to use any convenient format.

```
Start  | End    | Name
------ | ------ | -------------------
Dec 6  | Dec 7  | Saint Nicholas' Day
Dec 13 | Dec 14 | Saint Lucy's Day
Dec 24 | Dec 27 | Christmas
Jan 1  | Jan 2  | New Year
Jan 6  | Jan 7  | Epiphany
Feb 14 | Feb 15 | Valentine's Day
```

You are given a date as input (STDIN, function argument, or anything convenient) in `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format (e.g.: `2014-12-30 11:15:00`).

You may assume that the time zone is either UTC or the system's time zone. The holiday lasts from `00:00:00` on the start date (inclusive) to `00:00:00` on the end date (exclusive).

If the date falls within the range of the holiday, you must output `Happy <holiday>!`, except if it's Christmas, in which case you must output `Merry Christmas!`.

If it doesn't, but another holiday is coming at most a week in the future, you must output:

```
<time> left until <holiday>.
```

where `<time>` is in the following format:

```
<days>d <hours>h <minutes>m <seconds>s
```

You can't use a library for converting the time to that format.

If there are no whole days, hours, minutes or seconds remaining, omit the number entirely. For example, `1d 0h 3m 4s` should be printed as `1d 3m 4s`.

If there are no upcoming holidays, you must output (no pun intended):

```
There are no upcoming holidays.
```

A trailing newline is optional, but be consistent in your program—don't add a trailing newline in one case and omit it in another.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/344) are obviously forbidden.

### Test cases

```
Date                | Output
------------------- | ----------------------------------
2014-12-05 23:59:59 | 1s left until Saint Nicholas' Day.
2014-12-06 00:00:00 | Happy Saint Nicholas' Day!
2014-12-06 12:00:00 | Happy Saint Nicholas' Day!
2014-12-06 23:59:59 | Happy Saint Nicholas' Day!
2014-12-07 00:00:00 | 6d left until Saint Lucy's Day.
2014-12-14 00:00:00 | There are no upcoming holidays.
2014-12-24 00:00:00 | Merry Christmas!
```

Note that your program must work for any year, not just 2014.

### Winner

This is code golf, so the submission with the fewest number of bytes wins. An answer will be accepted after a week, but I'll be happy to change the accepted answer if a new valid submission beats the previous high score.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Comment: How do you expect people to test the test cases? It would probably be better to take input than to use the current time, because then it actually makes sense to talk about test cases. You should check [tag:date] for duplicates, and if there are none you should add that tag.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, I'll do that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I couldn't find any exact duplicates, only two [holiday-themed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3696/344) [questions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4106/344), both of which ask for much less than my challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## The Genetic Game of Life

In this game, you play as cells (as in cellular automata).  Your goal is to reproduce and kill off other cells on the board.

At the beginning of the game, two distinct configurations will be randomly chosen, one for reproduction, one for killing.  The configurations will consist of 3 squares in a 5 by 5 area, not including the center square.  For example,

```
OOXOX
OOOOO
OO OO
OOOXO
OOOOO
```

is an example configuration, where `X` represents a cell, and `O` can either be empty or filled. The configurations do not work if rotated.

The cells will be placed randomly, but equidistant from each other in a toroidal board.  Cells will be placed in a random turn order.

Each turn, each cell will move a square one at a time.  If a cell's movement creates the reproduction configuration *with cells of the same type*, and the center square is empty, then a new cell will spawn.  If a cell's movement creates the killing configuration *with cells of any type*, and the center square is filled, then the cell in the center square will die.

When a new cell spawns, its DNA will be conglomeration of the DNA of the bots in the configuration.  It will take its first turn after all other cells have taken 1 turn.

A cell that has not been part of a killing configuration after 200 turns will die.

The cell type with the most cells after 100K turns wins.

## IO

Each turn, you will be passed a string of 1s and 0s representing your DNA, and a list of 49 integers representing a 7x7 grid of the vision around the cell.  Specimens of the same type will have the same integer, and `0` will represent an empty square.

You must return a single character (`N`, `E`, `S`, `W` or `X`) representing the direction that the cell will travel.  Attempting to move into another cell will result in your cell not moving.

Comment: What size genome are you thinking?

Comment: When designing a bot, I think it would make a big difference if the total number of players was known. You could say "a game consists of 50 players competing on a board" and make up the numbers with a simple example bot if there are less than 50 answers. Obviously 50 is just an example - it could be 10 or 2 or 20 or whatever works best.

Comment: I say this because it means a bot writer will then know the maximum size of the 49 integers they need to process.

Comment: Could you specify whether a killing configuration can be made up using cells of different teams?

Comment: 1. The latest version of this question talks a lot about *types*, but doesn't define them. What is the *type* of a cell? Its genome? Its team? 2. What is meant by the "*conglomeration*" of the genomes of the bots in the spawning configuration? Is it the concatenation? Some kind of bit-by-bit random selection between the three parents' genomes? 3. What's the initial setup? How many cells do I get, and do they all have the same genome?

Answer (score 3):

## Convert a Finite State Machine to a Regular Expression

Anyone can make a finite state machine for matching a regular expression. But what about a regular expression that emulates a finite state machine? This inverse operation is much more confusing.

### Input

- A positive integer *N*, denoting the number of states in the machine. They are labeled 0 to *N - 1*.
- A list of accepting states of the machine. A string is considered to be accepted by the machine if it ends in one of these when there are no characters left.
- A list of triples (integer a, character b, integer c) representing the transition rules: when the machine is at state `a` and the current character in the string is `b`, then it may advance one character and move to state `c`.

You may specify the ordering and formatting of input.

### Output

A regular expression that matches a string iff it is accepted by the finite state machine.

#### Additional Rules

- An input for the state machine may contain only printable ASCII characters which are not in the set `^$()[]|+?*\.`.
- The machine begins in state `0`.
- You should not use any regex features other than `|`, `()`, `?`, `*`, `+`
- You may not use libraries designed for this task (which apparently exist).
- The regex should match full strings (assume it is surrounded by `^` and `$`).
- An answer is either a program which prints the regex to stdout, or a function which returns the regex.

This is code golf: write your code in as few bytes as possible.

### Sandbox Question

Should the FSM be deterministic or non?

Comment: Why not allow character classes? Alteration seems like an overkill alternative, and answers might like to detect parallel edges.

Comment: "a function which returns the regex." - do we need to actually construct the regex object or are we allowed to return a string representation thereof?

Comment: General FSMs tend to produce _really_ big regexes. Not sure if allowing non-determinism inflates that even further, but I believe it actually does not.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow `{` and `}` in the input? Because we'd have to escape these...

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks. I'll allow character classes although I doubt they would be used in golf. I'm aware they will be big (like [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/hard-code-golf-regex-for-divisibility-by-7)).

Comment: (a) Can we assume anything at all about the SM? Are all terminal states accepting? Are all states reachable? Can there be no reachable accepting states, and what would be the output in this case? (b) Are the blacklisted input chars also invalid as input for the regex? That is, can we use `\*` in our regex with the intention that it's never matched? (c) How liberal can we be with the input format? Can we take the transition table as, for example, `{src_state: [(char1, dest_state1), (char2, dest_state2)], ... }`, or must it be a list of triplets?

Comment: @Ell For (a) and (b), the metacharacters are not allowed in the input strings, so one way to match nothing would be using one of them literally. About (c), it must be a list of triples.

Answer (score 3):

## ASCII Robot Wars

This idea is based off of the game "Besiege" (which I've never played) and a previous sandboxed idea of mine called "Epic Customizable Tank Battle."

The main idea is that your program is the AI that controls a robot equipped with various weapons.  In this challenge, however, you will also have the opportunity to *design* your robot

## List of Parts

*(completely arbitrary and subject to total replacement)*

- Wooden planks `+` and armored metal plates `#` make up the body of the robot.
- Wheels `@` allow your robot to move.  TODO - turning
- Most weapons are formed with two parts, a body and a pointer `v^<>` to denote the direction of aim.
- Cannons have a body of `%`, ballistas have a body of (something), spikes and battering rams are (something).
- Maybe helicopter blades can be `X`.
- Banners, which serve no purpose but decoration, could be `$`.

### Example 5x5 robot

This robot has four wheels, three cannons facing forward, armored sides, and a flag in the middle.

```
@^^^@
#%%%#
#+$+#
#+++#
@###@
```

### Controlling the Bot

I think this would make a really cool Stack-Snippet KOTH, since it is "visually interesting" to watch robots blow each other into pieces.  Writing the controller will be hard because this is a major deviation from previous pixel-based KOTHs.

Answer (score 3):

## How to Gossip Appropriately

We all know how important it is to get social arrangements right:

[image: XKCD]

You have a group of friends who love to gossip. However, gossip is notorious for changing as it gets spread from friend to friend, and if somebody hears two versions of the same gossip, it just *ruins* it for them.

Hence, you and all of your friends have agreed to gossip in an orderly manner, and **it is your job to define who will gossip with who and for how long.  Ideal gossiping must follow the following rules**:

1. **Each friend must gossip for a specific amount of time**.  This time is different for each person.
2. **Any pair of friends will only spend so long gossiping**. Any longer, and it will become dull.  We will refer to this time as `L`.  This time is the same for all friends.
3. **Gossipping only comes in minute increments**.  We have no idea why this is, but its true.
4. **Gossip must eventually reach everybody**.  If any given friend has new gossip, then all of your friends must eventually get that gossip.
5. **Proper gossipping never includes circles**.  If `A` gossips to `B` and `C`, and then `B` gossips to `C`, then `C` will hear the news from two different people, and therefore, two different stories.

As an example say you are given the following as input:

[image: Graph]

Let's start by looking at `B`.  She prefers to gossip for only 1 minute, so she will only be able to gossip with one friend.

We know that she can't gossip with `D`, as that breaks rule #4

If we have `B` gossip with `C`, then `C` will have 1 minute of gossipping left, and `A` won't be able to fill his 2 minutes of gossipping needs.

Therefore, we know that `B` must gossip with `A` for 1 minute, and `A` must gossip for 1 minute with `C`.  `C` and `D` each have 1 minute of gossipping remaining, so they must both gossip with `E`.

`E` needs 2 more minutes of gossip.

If `E` gossips with `F` for 2 minutes, then gossip can't ever reach `G`.

If `E` gossips with `F` for 1 minute and `G` for 1 minute, then `F` must gossip with `H` for 1 minute, and `H` will then gossip with `G` for 2 minutes.  This will create a circle, breaking rule #5.

Therefore, we know that `E` gossips with `G` for 2 minutes, `G` gossips with `H` for 1 minute, and `H` gossips with `F` for 2 minutes.

Our final gossipping tree looks like:

[image: Tree]

---

Input will be in the following format, and will be passed to your program via STDIN (or closest alternative):

```
Max_Gossip_Time [Node0_Ideal_Gossip_Time, Node1_Ideal_Gossip_Time, ...] [[Node0, Node1], [Node0, Node1], ...]
```

The second array passed is the friend list, and are integers that refer to the positions in Ideal_Gossip_Time array.

The example above would be input as follows:

```
2 [2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3] [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [6, 7]]
```

Output should be to STDIO (or closest alternative) in the following format:

```
[[Node0, Node1, Gossip_Time], [Node0, Node2, Gossip_Time], ...]
```

On the above example, the output should be similar to:

```
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [4, 6, 2], [5, 7, 2], [6, 7, 1]]
```

On both input and output, the friend list can be in any order.

Comment: I didn't notice that you state anywhere that the weights must be integers. Some more test cases would be good. Do you know anything about the complexity class of this problem?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't think the complexity is too crazy, but I don't know it.  The hardest part of this challenge is actually ensuring that there are no cycles as min-maxing the edges will solve everything else.

Comment: I can see a research paper coming out of this!

Answer (score 3):

## Sorting Source Code [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Your task in this challenge is to write a program that takes no input and outputs `This program consists of` followed by your program's source code characters, but in alphabetical order.

### Details

- You may only use printable ASCII characters and line breaks in your program.
- When outputting all source code characters, ignore line breaks and sort all characters by their [ASCII number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) from lowest to highest.
- Reading your program's source code is not allowed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (in bytes) wins.

Here is a correctly ordered list of all printable ASCII characters (mind the space at the very beginning):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

### Example

If the source code for your program is

```
print 'This program consists of ';
print this.sort();
```

then output must be

```
This program consists of       ''().;;Tacfghhiiiiimnnnooooppprrrrrssssssttttt
```

Comment: You should probably add the [tag:quine] tag to this. And you should also specify whether reading the source code is allowed. That said, I'm not sure how much it adds over existing (generalised) quine challenges. Ultimately, solutions will just be language's standard quine, followed by sorting the string and prepending `This program consists of`.

Comment: Are submissions in which the original source code is already sorted, allowed?

Comment: @ProgramFOX: I don't see why they shouldn't be allowed. Is there any particular reason?

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Good point. I've added the quine tag, but probably there's no point in posting this challenge if there are already enough similar questions!

Comment: @vauge No, I missed that you had to print a sentence before the sorted characters. Initially I thought of a one-char solution like `1` which works in some languages (and which would pretty much miss the purpose of the challenge), but of course that doesn't print the sentence.

Comment: In addition to not reading the source code, you might want to link [to these working definitions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4877/8478) of what counts as a proper quine. With the requirement of printing the additional string it's not very likely that there are a lot of loopholes left, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: The problem with quines is that there's a reusable technique to print any function of the source code, so twists like this don't actually change much.

Answer (score 3):

Strange question about transit schematics (title tbd)

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

In this challenge, your goal is to produce a schematic diagram of a transit network, given a list of lines and a list of stations as input. This is a popularity-contest -- the program's goal is to maximize the readability of the diagram by carefully choosing where to draw the stations and lines.

Each line in the transit network is formatted as a list of strings. For instance:

```
"Peel Line", "Douglas", "Port Erin", "Braddan Halt", "Union Mill", "Crosby"
```

The first string on the list is the name of the line. The remaining strings are the stations that that particular line stops at. In this example the Peel Line stops at Douglas, Port Erin, Braddan Halt, Union Mill, and terminates at Crosby. The lines are bidirectional so the Peel Line would also go back the other way.

Of course, most transit networks will have more than one line. Each line of the transit network will have its own line in the input. For instance:

```
"Peel Line", "Douglas", "Port Erin", "Braddan Halt", "Union Mill", "Crosby"
"Foxdale Line", "Ramsey", "St. John's", "Union Mill", "Bishop", "Foxdale"
```

Notice how both lines stop at Union Mill. This means that Union Mill is an interchange station for those two lines. A station is an interchange station if more than one line stops at it. Here is an attempt at what the network might look like:

[image: bad map]

This map does some things well but fails at other things. The lines are coloured different colours which helps differentiate the lines. In addition, the interchange station is emphasised with the white dot to show it is an interchange station. However, it fails at other things, the most prominent being that the text "Union Mill" is overlapping the line, and there is a lack of a key showing which line is which. When we fix these elements the map looks like this:

[image: another map!]

Much better! (Another way I could have resolved the Union Mill overlapping issue was to change the paths of the lines.) In addition, we can also have  lines being a loop. This is indicated by the first and last train stations being the same. For instance:

```
"Island Line", "Port Erin", "Kitterland", "Kalfr", "Ardglass", "Kearney", "Port Erin"
```

The Island Line in this case is a loop that goes from Port Erin to Kitterland to Kalfr, then to Ardglass and Kearney, before finally returning to Port Erin, completing the loop.

With more complicated train networks, it becomes more difficult to arrange the stations and lines in a readable manner. Here are some inputs of varying complexity and density to try your program on. Some of them are based of actual networks, while others are made up for this challenge.

Challenge Input 1: Oslo, Norway:

```
"1", "Frognerseteren", "Voksenkollen", "Lillevann", "Skogen", "Voksenlia", "Holmenkollen", "Besserud", "Midtstuen", "Skådalen", "Vettakollen", "Gulleråsen", "Gråkammen", "Slemdal", "Ris", "Gaustad", "Vinderen", "Steinerud", "Frøen", "Majorstuen", "Nationaltheatret", "Stortinget", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Grønland", "Tøyen", "Ensjø", "Helsfyr", "Brynseng", "Hellerud", "Tveita", "Haugerud", "Trosterud", "Lindeberg", "Furuset", "Ellingsrudåsen"
"2", "Østerås", "Lijordet", "Eiksmarka", "Ekravein", "Røa", "Hovseter", "Holmen", "Makrellbekken", "Smestad", "Borgen", "Majorstuen", "Nationaltheatret", "Stortinget", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Grønland", "Tøyen", "Ensjø", "Helsfyr", "Brynseng", "Hellerud", "Tveita", "Haugerud", "Trosterud", "Lindeberg", "Furuset", "Ellingsrudåsen"
"3", "Mortensrud", "Skullerud", "Bogerud", "Bøler", "Ulsrud", "Oppsal", "Skøyenåsen", "Godlia", "Hellerud", "Brynseng", "Helsfyr", "Ensjø", "Tøyen", "Grønland", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Stortinget", "Nationaltheatret", "Majorstuen", "Blindern", "Forskningsparken", "Ullevål stadion", "Berg", "Tåsen", "Østhorn", "Holstein", "Kringsjå", "Sognsvann"
"4", "Storo", "Nydalen", "Ullevål stadion", "Forskningsparken", "Blindern", "Majorstuen", "Nationaltheatret", "Stortinget", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Grønland", "Tøyen", "Ensjø", "Helsfyr", "Brynseng", "Høyenhall", "Manglerud", "Ryen", "Brattlikollen", "Karlsrud", "Lambertseter", "Munkelia", "Bergkrystallen"
"5", "Storo", "Nydalen", "Ullevål stadion", "Forskningsparken", "Blindern", "Majorstuen", "Nationaltheatret", "Stortinget", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Grønland", "Tøyen", "Carl Berners plass", "Hasle", "Økern", "Risløkka", "Vollebekk", "Linderud", "Veitvet", "Rødtvet", "Kalbakken", "Ammerud", "Grorud", "Romsås", "Rommen", "Stovner", "Vestli"
"6", "Bekkestua", "Ringstabekk", "Jar", "Bjørnsletta", "Åsjordet", "Ullernåsen", "Montebello", "Smestad", "Borgen", "Majorstuen", "Nationaltheatret", "Stortinget", "Jernbanetorget (Oslo S)", "Grønland", "Tøyen", "Carl Berners plass", "Sinsen", "Storo"
```

Here's what the official map looks like for some inspiration (click to enlarge):

[image: OSLO!!!]

```
TODO: more challenge inputs coming!
```

**Sandbox Notes**

- I've had this one sitting around for a while. I've wanted to try and make a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) that wasn't just about making the prettiest image. So instead it's about making the most functional image, which I'm not sure is any better than the art challenges...
- Another thing I've been considering is changing it to a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). I'd have minimum requirements for the final output (a key, coloured lines, distinguished interchange stations, etc.) and the shortest code that implemented all the requirements would win. I'd like your thoughts on whether this challenge would work better as code golf or popularity contest.

Comment: I like this concept, but I *somewhat* like it better as a popcon. As a golf, you will get the bare minimum requirements for sure, and it might not be very functional/readable at all. As a popcon, you'll probably get at least a couple platform-ready posters. I don't normally recommend popcon for things that could be golfed, but this feels like one them.

Comment: For test cases, I think [Tokyo](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/info/map_a4ol.pdf) would make for something nice and complicated.

Comment: @Geobits That is a fantastically complicated network, but it's got all sorts of things that the input format can't handle -- if I'm reading it right, when the Yokosuka Line reaches Chiba and Soga it splits off into different paths with different terminus stations.

Comment: Good point, I'm guessing many large cities have split lines like that. I suppose if you want a simple input format it'll have to be some boring old map ;)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an obvious reason for not using an input format which allows lines to fork and loops to encompass only part of a line. Why not take input in a subset of the .dot format?

Answer (score 3):

## Permutations of the Fifteen Puzzle

## [POSTED](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50819/31054)

Answer (score 3):

## Invisible target - probability KotH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) *[probability-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory)* *?*

---

### In short

**Walls are gradually added and the player nearest to the stationary invisible target at the end of the game wins.**

---

### Detail

Players are all present on a 32 by 32 grid of square cells, which wraps toroidally. One randomly chosen cell is the target, which is not indicated to any of the players (regardless of whether they are on that cell or not). The target does not move.

Players all take their turn simultaneously. After each turn there is a small chance of a wall being added.

#### Wall rules

- The wall will never be placed on a player.
- The wall will never be placed in a cell that does not have a route to the target.
- Of the possible positions for the wall to be placed, one will be chosen uniformly pseudorandomly.
- The probability of a wall being placed each turn is 1/7.
- The wall will be placed such that every player still has a route to the target (this includes never placing a wall on the target).

Note that a player having a route to the target means that there exists a path that does not include a wall. If another player blocks the path it still counts as a path.

#### Movement rules

- A player can move to any of the 4 orthogonally adjacent cells (or stay still).
- A player cannot share a cell with another player.
- A player cannot move onto a wall.
- A player *can* move onto the target, but will have no way of knowing that this has happened.

#### Starting position

At the start of the game the arena will have no walls and the players will be randomly positioned with the guarantee that there are no other players within each player's 5 by 5 neighbourhood.

#### Winning

Play will continue until no wall can be placed for 10 consecutive attempts (note that attempts only occur with probability 1/7 each turn so this will take more than 10 turns). When play stops the player closest to the target (by Manhattan distance) is the winner. Although this makes it possible to have an arbitrary number of joint winners, the density of walls by this point makes it unlikely there will be many, and in most cases there will be a player on the target cell, meaning only a single winner.

Each of the (one or several) joint winners scores one point. Games will be played until one player is the clear winner, or until it is clear there should be joint winners overall.

---

### Input and output

#### Input

During an N player game the input will be a space separated string of N+1 integers received on STDIN:

- The player's position (an integer).
- The position of any wall added since the player's last turn (an integer).
- The position of every enemy player (N-1 integers).

Positions will be single integers from 0 to 1023, representing the distance in English reading order from the top left cell.

For a 4 by 4 arena this would give the following numbering:

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

If no wall was added the wall location will be 1024.

During a particular game the order of enemy players will be consistent - the nth location will always refer to the same enemy player.

#### Output

The player must send an integer from 0 to 4 to STDOUT representing a move in English reading order:

```
  0
1 2 3
  4
```

(2 being no move).

A move to an unoccupied cell will not necessarily succeed - it will fail if another player is also trying to move to the same cell.

A move to an occupied cell will not necessarily fail - it will succeed if that player is also moving away from that cell (provided that player succeeds in moving away from that cell, and no other player is also trying to move to that cell).

This means two players can swap cells if they both decide to on the same turn.

A player taking longer than 50 milliseconds to respond will not move.

---

## Sandbox questions

- If someone can demonstrate that there can exist no better strategy than moving uniformly randomly, then I will not post this challenge. I'm hoping that the knowledge of the rules behind wall placement and the ability to block the movement of other players will make probability estimating competitive strategies non-trivial. ***This is answered - Nathan Merrill's strategy of moving to the reachable cell whose maximum distance to any other reachable cell is the shortest will beat the strategy of moving uniformly randomly (although in a crowded arena I don't believe this will be the* best *strategy so I still consider the question worth posting***).
- Should this be tagged [probability-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory)? I am expecting answers to make use of probability theory, but I can't know in advance what all the strategies will be. Is this close enough to use the tag?
- I'm aiming for this to be a language agnostic challenge communicating with STDIN/STDOUT. Is there a language that is overdue to have its own language specific KotH contest, but that would still allow most users to participate? If not, I'll stick with language agnostic and include at least one example answer so that the processing of STDIN and STDOUT is provided in at least one language.
- Method for deciding which attempted moves succeed. Is there any problem with this: Make a list of every intended destination (including own current cell for non-movers). For any destination that appears more than once, make all players aiming for that destination aim for their own current cell instead. Repeat (as this may have created more clashes) until no change is made. Move all the players to the resulting destination. Guaranteed to finish in N steps per turn for an N player game (worst case being a chain of players each moving to the next player's current cell, with the last player in the chain attempting to move onto a wall).
- Pseudo random number source: Does anyone have a preferred/recommended random number generator? Is there any reason to consider a true random number source?
- ***Alternative adversarial 2 player version:*** One player is the target, and the other player is seeking the target. Each player can move one square orthogonally or stay still. Walls are added as in the multiplayer game, and the game ends when the seeker moves onto the target's cell. The score of each player is the number of moves the game lasted. Lower score is better for the seeker player, higher score is better for the target player. The target can always see the location of the seeker. The seeker can never see the location of the target. Might also be interesting to allow both players to choose where to place a wall on their turn (in addition to moving). This might open up the possibility of double bluff. Walls would still be prevented from being placed on a cell that doesn't leave a path from seeker to target. Would this be more/less interesting than the multiplayer version? Are they sufficiently distinct to post as separate challenges, or should one be chosen as the one to be posted? Would this adversarial version work best as two KotHs that use each other's answers to judge their own answers (like a cops and robbers challenge) or should all the seeker answers and target answers be posted to one challenge? Alternatively each answer could be required to deal with being either a seeker or a target, but I like the idea of people being able to specialise and build just one or other, without being obliged to write both.

Comment: I believe the best strategy is to take all of the connected squares, and find the one that has the shortest walking distance to all other squares.  Also, I think that walls should be placed every turn, as it appears to only slow down the game.

Comment: Also, I believe an interesting variant would be to have it more like the cats/mice KotH, where several mice compete to stand on the square first, and the cat tries to delay them as long as possible.

Comment: @NathanMerrill thanks for the feedback. When you say walls should be placed every turn, do you mean each time any player moves, or each time all N players have moved?

Comment: Each time all N players have moved, although I wouldn't be against the other either.

Comment: Would the variant involve a cat that knows the position of the target?

Comment: Yes, it would (wouldn't be interesting otherwise, I think)

Comment: @NathanMerrill my problem with adding the wall at the same point each time, after N players have moved, is that this means the players at the start of the cycle get first choice about where to move, which becomes more relevant in the later stages of the game.

Comment: Then I would add a wall after N+1 players have taken a turn, or rotate the player's turns

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I'll consider changing it to that (N + 1 turns between walls)

Comment: I'm not against several moves per player between walls though. I've chosen the arena small enough to allow a large number of moves in total, and the cell a player wishes to be on may be several cells away from the current cell, so I don't feel a strong need to add walls at high frequency.

Comment: Moving to the center of the arena may well be worse than a uniformly random strategy ;) There's definitely one better than random though.

Comment: Question: will player bots have information storage? That is, will a player be able to remember every wall that has been placed?

Comment: @Draco18s yes the players will persist between moves, and can store information. I may place an upper limit on the amount of storage, but if I do it will be very generous.

Comment: In which case, moving randomly is *not* the best strategy :)

Comment: No, I'm thinking not, especially as a player can track what all of the other players are doing (they are distinguishable from each other, not just generic "enemy", but "player 1", "player 2", ...)

Answer (score 3):

## Multiples - a wrap battle

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

### Overview

**Change cells in multiples to wipe out your opponent, while avoiding being wiped out yourself.**

---

This is a 2 player game, played on a linear string of cells of length L that wrap in a loop. Counting along the loop eventually brings you back to where you started (after L steps). L will be fixed across all battles, and will be a reasonably large prime.

Each cell is controlled by player 1, player 2, or is neutral. These will be indicated as 1, 2 and 0 respectively.

#### Starting position

Player 2 starts with a cell at position 0 (since all are equivalent).

Player 1 starts with a randomly chosen cell from 1 to floor(L/2).

Player 1 moves first, reflecting the fact that player 1 has further to go to catch player 2.

#### Taking a turn

Each player begins with a stockpile of 0, and at the start of each turn the player's stockpile is increased by the number of cells that they currently control. The player then takes their turn. They choose any cell they control and specify a number N, which can be any non-negative integer up to and including the size of the stockpile. The stockpile is reduced by this number, and N loop cells are affected as follows:

Starting with the chosen cell as cell 0, each of the cells N, 2N, 3N, ... N*N are changed.

- Choosing 0 means nothing happens, at zero cost.
- Choosing 1 means the cell immediately after the chosen cell is changed, at a cost of 1.
- Choosing 2 means the cell 2 cells on and the cell 4 cells on are changed, at a cost of 2.
- Choosing 3 means the cells 3, 6 and 9 cells on are changed, at a cost of 3.
- In general, choosing N changes N cells at a cost of N.

When a cell is changed it follows the following rules:

- A neutral cell becomes the player's.
- An enemy cell becomes neutral.
- A cell already owned by the player becomes the enemy's

#### Large N

I expect most moves will choose N considerably smaller, but saving up would allow choosing N considerably larger than L in theory.

Choosing N=L means that all of the changed cells will be the same - the chosen cell, and it will be changed L times.

Choosing N=L-1 means that the L-1 consecutive cells before the chosen cell will all be changed (that is, every cell except the chosen one will be changed).

#### Winning

If a move leaves no enemy cells remaining, that player wins.

After 1000 moves any player who has more cells than their enemy at the start of 2 consecutive turns in a row (one theirs, one their enemy's, in either order) wins.

After 2000 moves the game is a draw (tie).

---

### Input and output

#### Input

At the start of a game the player's code will be called with a command line argument of 1 or 2 indicating which player they are (player 1 moves first and is represented by 1s in the loop string).

Each turn the player will be supplied with:

- A string of 0s, 1s and 2s representing the loop.
- An integer S representing the size of their stockpile.
- An integer R representing the size of their opponent's stockpile.
- An integer representing the number of turns taken so far (this will always be an even number for player 1).

#### Output

The player should output 2 integers:

- The cell C to play from, in the range 0 <= C < L.
- The number of cells to change N, in the range 0 <= N <= S (their current stockpile size).

---

## Sandbox questions

- I like the idea of this being a 1 dimensional game, but I can also see it working on a 2d grid, where each move is applied both horizontally and vertically (either on a square L by L, or with 2 distinct large primes as side lengths). Does anyone have anything for or against either 1d or 2d?
- Any recommendations on what input to provide? I was thinking at least the values of all the cells, but would a history also be good, or better to make the players decide what history to track for themselves rather than providing it? Alternatively they could be memoryless and decide purely based on the current cell formation.
- Is the random starting position a good idea? Would it be better to fix the starting position at floor(L/2), ensuring this number is prime, and let the players taking turns to be player 1 balance out any bias?

Answer (score 3):

### Group Students Into Pairs

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)

> **Synopsis**: A graph theory matching problem. Given a list of which students like and dislike each other, pair the students up to maximise the overal happiness of the classroom.

### Introduction

If you've ever been a teacher before, you've likely encountered the extremely frustrating experience that is getting students to do pair work. More often than not no one is happy with their partner, and the mood of the classroom suffers.

In this challenge, we're going to solve the enduring problem of pair work in classrooms. Here's how our system will work:

1. Each student shall write down what students they are happy to work with, and which ones they are *not* happy to work with.
2. We will take those lists, and generate student pairs such that the total *happiness* of the classroom is at its maximum.
3. The students are now (mostly) happy!

So how is the happiness of the classroom calculated? For each student in each pair of students:

- If a student's partner is in their "happy to work with" list, increase the happiness of the classroom by 1.
- If a student's partner is in their "not happy to work with" list, decrease the happiness of the classroom by 1.
- If a student is neutral towards their partner (not in either list), the happiness of the classroom does not change.

Here's a useful table that summarises the possible changes in the happiness with each pair of students:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Student 1 Feeling | Student 2 Feeling | Happiness Modifier |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Happy!            | Happy!            | +2                 |
| Happy!            | Neutral           | +1                 |
| Happy!            | Not happy...      | 0                  |
| Neutral           | Happy!            | +1                 |
| Neutral           | Neutral           | 0                  |
| Neutral           | Not happy...      | -1                 |
| Not happy...      | Happy!            | 0                  |
| Not happy...      | Neutral           | -1                 |
| Not happy...      | Not happy...      | -2                 |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

### Input

First line of input is a positive integer `n` indicating the number of students to match up. `n` is always even. Following that are `n` lines, each line which has the format:

```
name likes dislikes
```

where `name` is the name of the student (which will only contain characters from `[A-Za-z]`), `likes` is a comma separated list of people he or she would be happy to work with, and `dislikes` is a comma separated list of people he or she would not be happy to work with. For instance:

```
Clarence Tiger,Anna,Jamal Amelia,James
```

This would indicate that Clarence is happy to work with Tiger, Anna, or Jamal; he is not happy to work with Amelia or James; and towards any other student he is neutral.

Another line:

```
Ilya Amelia,Clarence,Anna,Tiger,Jamal _
```

This would indicate that Ilya is happy to work with Amelia, Clarence, Anna, Tiger, and Jamal. For dislikes, we've used the special keyword `_`, which indicates that Ilya doesn't have anyone he is not happy to work with. Any remaining students Ilya would be neutral towards.

### Output

Output space separated comma separated pairs of names, where each name corresponds to a pair of students. The pairs should be such that the happiness of the classroom is maximised. Every student should be in exactly one pair.

### Example Inputs and Outputs

Writing reference implementation. This is one of those types of questions where you can't really judge the correct output for an input "by eye".

### Sandbox Questions

1. This problem is quite difficult compared to typical code-golf fare, requiring two different algorithms to solve the weighted maximum matching problem. Is it too difficult for a code-golf? And if it is, what could make a better winning criterion?

Comment: It's certainly not too difficult for a code golf at present, because there are no time constraints so I could brute-force it. With time constraints I'd have to do some research before tackling it, but it's good to have the occasional code golf problem which can't be solved in 30 characters.

Comment: I would think the challenge would actually do well with a loose time constraint to prevent brute force.  While you'd definitely get fewer answers, those answers would definitely be more interesting

Comment: "_Jamal Amelia_" -- Where is the comma? And I think that this would be fine for code-golf. BTW, add which all characters a name could have in the challenge.

Comment: @CoolGuy There's no space because `Jamal` is the end of the likes and `Amelia` is the start of the dislikes. I added in which characters a name can contain.

Comment: Cool Guy's question raises the point that you should be explicit about cases where a person has no likes, no dislikes, or neither. I.e. can trailing spaces be omitted? Can the entire line be omitted if the person has neither likes nor dislikes but is liked or disliked by someone else?

Answer (score 3):

**Help Indiana Jones and his crew cross the bridge!**

This codegolf will solve the [Bridge and Torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_and_torch_problem) problem. In this problem, there are multiple people (I'm thinking four) who must all cross a weak bridge to escape an evil dragon as quickly as possible. Because the bridge is weak, only two people can cross the bridge at a time. The whole crew is armed with one torch, which is necessary for 1 or 2 people to cross the bridge. Furthermore, each person takes a certain, integral amount of time to cross the bridge. When two people cross together, they must run at the rate of the slower person. The whole crew needs to quickly figure out how to get all the people across the bridge in the least amount of time to maximize their chances of survival.

**Input** 
A list of names of the crew (one word, a-zA-Z) and how long they take to cross the bridge alone.

**Output** An explanation of who crosses the bridge in which order so that the total time is minimized, and the total time.

**Example** 
Input: `Indiana 5 Jones 10`

Output:

`Indiana, Jones 
10`

Input: `A 1 B 2 C 5 D 8`

Output:

`A, B
A
C, D
B
A, B
15`

I'm thinking of either just solving this problem with any number of people, or another version in which anyone not at the end (ie. on the first side or on the bridge) after the time limit dies, and the goal is to minimize the number of deaths.

Comment: If it's code-golf it's easier for you as the question poster. If you put a time limit, then different computers will achieve different amounts in that time limit, so you would need to run all the answers on your own computer to give them an official score.

Answer (score 3):

## If it floats, it boats!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The goal of this challenge is to determine whether or not an ASCII-art shape will float.  Like any other boat, ASCII boats obey the law of buoyancy: it will float if it displaces an equal mass of water.

ASCII boats are made out of `O` characters arranged in some contiguous shape (diagonals are connected).  There may be trailing spaces, but the whole input is a rectangle (trailing newline optional). Example boat:

```
   O         O    
    O        O    
     OOOOOOOOO
```

The material of the boat has twice the density of water.  When a boat is *floating*, the number of displaced water characters is at least twice number of `O` character in the boat.  Here is an artist's impression of a boat while floating.

```
   O         O    
~~~~O        O~~~~
~~~~~OOOOOOOOO~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This boat has 13 `O` characters, but displaces 19 water characters, so it floats.

The key to floating is the creation of an air pocket.  Air pockets can be formed in two ways:  either the water cannot reach the pocket (because the boat has walls keeping it out), or air is trapped in the pocket and cannot escape.  Here's an example of a capsized boat which can still float (warning: do not attempt at home).

```
     OOOOOOOOO
~~~~O        O~~~~
~~~O         O~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The following shapes aren't boats because they can't float:

```
OOO
O  
O  
O  
OOO

   O         O    
    O        O    
     OOOOOOOOO    
             O    
         OOOOOOOOO
         OOOOOOOOO
         OOOOOOOOO
```

## The Goal

Write a program that, when given an ASCII-art shape, outputs a truthy value if it boats, and a falsey value if it doesn't boat.  This is code golf, fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Do you want this to be the simple version (if it displaces enough water it floats) or a more complex version (some of the air spaces may be filled as it sinks, but remaining air spaces are sufficient to keep it afloat). I'm thinking of examples with multiple air spaces with different height walls, so at a certain depth the water can only fill some of them. That is, the weight of the boat is too great to keep all of the air spaces empty, but the remaining ones are sufficient to keep it from sinking any further.

Comment: 1. Bearing in mind the example of the capsized boat: are we supposed to test all possible rotations of the input, or just the orientation in which it's supplied? 2. It would be good to have test cases which are right on the edge (one which floats by displacing exactly its mass, and one which is one unit too heavy). 3. Another corner case which isn't mentioned is discontiguous boats. Should we assume that the input is fully connected?

Comment: @trichoplax I am leaning towards the more complex version, where the boat is "lowered into" the water, which may float various parts until the equilibrium is reached.  PeterTaylor  I'll say that only the given orientation should be tested.  Also, boats will always be contiguous.

Comment: Why are the non-boat example not boats? Or do you mean they are boats that don't float?

Comment: @xnor They don't float.  It was supposed to be an extension of "if it floats, it boats" so the ones that don't float aren't boats.

Comment: The boat has 13 O characters, and the material is twice the density of water. Doesn't it therefore need to displace 26 characters in order to float? Sure, this shape will float but it will sit lower in the water than you have drawn it.

Answer (score 3):

## Bad Lip Reading Generator

A malapropism is the substitution of one word for another that sounds similar, often as a way to make something sound unintentionally humorous.  For example, "He's a wolf in *cheap* clothing" is a malapropism, since the expected word, "sheep's", got replaced by "cheap", which sounds similar but means something different.

A modern version of malapropism is to take scenes from movies and redub the dialog with different words that match the actors mouth movements as a
parody.  There is a YouTube channel called "[Bad Lip Reading](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjADahUKEwiT0IKLq7jHAhVFjpIKHZU-CDg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fuser%2FBadLipReading&ei=mCLWVZOkE8WcygSV_aDAAw&usg=AFQjCNFx9AIC3sy1OUXrEll90DpQ2rmqrg)" that uses this technique.

I would like to apply the process to some old videos with subtitle files, then watch the videos with the sound turned down to turn it into a long series of malapropisms.

Using mouth movements gives a more flexible range of malapropism so there is some flexibility between different sounds.

#### Challenge

Create a malapropism generator.  I want to be able to feed text from subtitles into the generator and have text which is different, but still matches the mouth movements of the actors.

#### Input

A string of English words, (already processed to remove punctuation and forced to uppercase).

#### Output

A string of English words, (same format as input).

#### Notes

To simplify the challenge, all input words are in upper case, separated by whitespace, with all punctuation except apostrophes removed.

Lets agree to constraint what words "sound like", to be based on the [CMUDICT](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b).  You may scrub the data so you don't have to worry about
comments or special punctuation entries and remove stress numbers.

Lets also agree on the mouth-movements associated with the sounds, called
"visemes".  Here is a mapping used by Microsoft's SAPI library, which is
itself based on Disney animation rules.  Microsoft uses the same set of phonemes from [ARPABet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet) as CMUDict data.

```
#   ARPAbet Phoneme

1   AE AH
2   AA
3   AO
4   EH EY UH
5   ER
6   IH IY Y
7   UW W
8   OW
9   AW
10  OY
11  AY
12  HH
13  R
14  L
15  S  Z
16  CH JH SH ZH
17  DH TH
18  F  V
19  D  N  T
20  G  K  NG
21  B  M  P
```

You should be able to take each English word, convert to a set of phonemes, then to a set of visemes, then produce a list of words with matching visemes and randomly select one of the other words from the list.  If a word doesn't match, or doesn't have any alternative, the original word should be copied to output.

#### Examples

- "HELLO WORLD"           "HALLOW WHIRLED"
- "I SEE DEAD PEOPLE"     "EYE SEA TED PEOPLE"
- "I WILL BE BACK"        "EYE WHEEL PEA BAG"
- "IT WAS BEAUTY KILLED THE BEAST"    "INN WAS PUNY GILT THE MIST"
- "MAY THE FORCE BE WITH YOU" "MAY THE FOURS BEE WITH YEW"

#### Test Cases

Since the words are random, I have selected some pairs of words with unique pronunciation.  Your function or program should always return one word when presented with the other:

```
Input            Output
"AMUSING"        "ABUSING"
"APOGEE"         "APACHE"
"BACKDATING"     "MAGNETIC"
"BALLOONING"     "POLLUTING"
"INVISIBLE"      "INFEASIBLE"
"LAMPS"          "LUMPS"
"SCORN"          "SCORED"
"WEPT"           "WEBBED"
```

#### Rules

- You can write a full program or function.
- Input should be taken from stdin or function parameters.
  Output should be printed through stdout or returned.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf]. Submission with least number of bytes, (not including data file(s)) wins.

Comment: Interesting challenge, but I have some small suggestions. 1. The example in the first paragraph (*moths* vs *moss*) is inconsistent with the definition which follows, and that could confuse. Maybe borrow one of the test cases, or mention *The Importance of being Earnest*? 2. Why not link to the YouTube channel? 3. For subheadings, `###` is better than `*`. 4. Since the input is nicely cleaned, I can't see why you specify *all input words are in the same case* rather than *all input words are in upper case*. The latter would be more useful, since it matches the CMUDICT file.

Comment: 5. The mapping of ARPAbet to viseme ID is very long and offputting, and it's not really necessary. If you replace it by a list of groups (`AE AH` newline ... newline `B M P`) in preformatted text (indent by four spaces) then it will convey all the necessary information while taking a lot less space. 6. Talking of which, it might be worth mentioning ARPAbet to pre-empt questions in the comments.

Comment: 7. It's a good idea to be explicit that when you say *randomly* you mean *with equal probability* or (easier for those whose libraries give them random floats) *with a difference between the greater and least probabilities of no more than 1%*. 8. The test cases aren't very useful for testing. The most useful test cases will be where most of the words have one or two possible outputs. E.g. *MINT CONDITION STAMPS* becomes *PINNED CONDITION STUMPS*. *CATERER* is also a good test case because it has a repeated phoneme at the end of the word, which could catch some buggy regex-based approaches.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/cake-its-somebodys-birthday)

---

*Concerns:*

- <strike>I'm not sure how well single language questions do. It automatically limits the question to those that already know the language, and those that are willing to learn just for this question.</strike> There's no need to limit to Chef with some of the magic this community can produce!
- "selfish/demanding" sounds quite strong and could sound like a bit of a personal attack on Beta Decay. It certainly isn't intended like that, and I expect it will be accepted as intended, but is it better to err on the side of caution?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to limit the challenge to Chef? Writing code that mimics a real world cake recipe could be entertaining in other languages as well.

Comment: @Dennis, I suppose not! I wouldn't have thought it possible, but I've seen some of the magic this community can produce!

Comment: I feel like the best tasting submission might just be an actual cake recipe which acts as a no-op, with the actual printing merely tacked on somewhere (eg in Foo)

Comment: @Sp3000, that's possible. I added that rule because with Chef, the ratios for ingredients are often way off.

Answer (score 3):

### Source code ecological footprint

You've just been hired by a German car manufacturing company.
Your first task, as an engineer, is to write a program that computes the ecological footprint of source code.

The ecological footprint of a character is computed as follows (you can assume the source code is ASCII-encoded):

> Write the character's ASCII code in binary, and count the number of 1's.

For example, `A` has a footprint of 2, but `O` is dirtier with a footprint of 5.

> The global footprint of a program is the sum of the footprints of its characters.

Your program must accept a string as parameter, compute its ecological footprint, and output it.

There is a subtlety though. As you wish to enter a new, more restrictive market, you need to tune your program so that it behaves differently in "test mode".
Thus:

> The program should output 0 when it receives the string `test` as parameter.

**Scoring**

The source code with the smaller ecological footprint wins (and yes, the answer `test` is forbidden!)

Comment: This anonymous company doesn't happen to be named *Volt's Wagons*, does it?

Comment: @Zach Sorry, I rolled back your edits - the horizontal lines were really harming readability ? and the fact that we output `0` only when we receive test is important ?

Comment: You could have removed the `hr` tags.. Also, I added a *lot* of punctuation and grammar fixes.. I didn't removed the "output 0 only when we receive test" detail either? I only removed the redundant clause.

Comment: What's the expected output for an empty input string? I'd normally say `0`, but "*(and only when)*" seems to disqualify that.

Comment: @Zach I've re-reported your changes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can we assume that the input will never be empty?

Comment: @Zach I would accept empty input and output 0, as the footprint of an empty program is zero ?

Answer (score 3):

This has been donated to the [Secret Santa Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10429/42963) if anyone wants to take up the mantle.

## Crazy Librarian's Interesting Numbers Game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

Phew, you just managed to finish your code for the [Arithmetic Sequence of Primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59736/42963), and everything went swimmingly for your Crazy Librarian boss. Indeed, the math teacher taught the librarian a new card game as thanks for the prime sequences. However, the librarian wants to beat the math teacher at their own game, and so you're enlisted (again) to assist.

The card game was described as a two-player variation of a trick-taking game called *California Jack*. Each player is dealt a particular suit of cards from a standard US 52-card deck, and this forms their hand. A third suit of the cards is randomly shuffled and placed face-down between the players as the trophy deck. The fourth suit is unused. Each round, the top of the trophy deck is flipped face-up, and the two players select a card (in secret) from their hand to be their bid for that round, and places it face-down in front of them. The players reveal their bid card, and the higher card (aces low) wins the trophy card. The trophy card goes into the winner's trophy pile, and the two bid cards are discarded. If the players both bid the same card, neither gets the trophy card, and it is discarded along with both bid cards. The winner after all 13 rounds is whoever has the most points in their trophy pile, with Jack=11, Queen=12, and King=13. Note that it is possible for the game to end in a draw (including a zero-point draw).

Since you really want to impress the Crazy Librarian, you've ... enlisted ... the help of some of your friends, and you're going to create a bracket royale to find the best playing algorithm, and use that so the librarian can show up the math teacher.

---

#### Questions for Meta

- Program I/O? I'm envisioning a stateful program that keeps track of its own cards, where each execution is a run of the game against an outside opponent -- e.g., each input is `[W/L] T#` that says whether the program `W`on or `L`ost the previous round, and what the current-round's `T`rophy card is. Then, the output would be what card it chooses to bid. Repeat 13 times. Could also do an interactive version, scraping STDOUT and setting STDIN?
- Example of a really simplistic algorithm (in pseudocode) -- `return argv[1]` -- this just bids the same as whatever the trophy card is.
- The programs could keep track of their opponent's total and their total, but the controller would have final say (obviously).
- I'm envisioning a double-bracket style, where each program is randomly seeded into the bracket. Best 3-of-5 games moves it to the next round, while the loser gets re-seeded into the loser's bracket and can re-win a chance for the final four.
- What am I missing?

Comment: I think input could be expanded a bit. For instance, there doesn't seem to be any way to track your opponent's cards right now (just whether it won/lost the last), even though in an actual game they would be revealed (and would be part of any decent strategy I'd think).

Answer (score 3):

## Planting Steiner Trees

[programming-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

In the following we are talking about 
Steiner trees, which are similar to minimal spanning trees: The goal is connecting all nodes via some paths such that the resulting graph that is as short as possible. In contrast to minimal spanning trees when constructing steiner trees you can add additional nodes.

In the following we are talking about points in the real 2d plane and when we are talking about distances and lengths, we are talking about the *euclidean distance*.

Also, a graph will comprise a set of points where the edges are straight lines between pairs of those points. The length of a graph will be the sum of the length of all edges.

So a steiner tree is a shortest graph connecting all given points possibly with inserting additional points. The following image shows the difference between a minimall spanning tree (blue) and a steiner tree (red).

It is known that it is very difficult to find steiner trees.

[image]

## Task

Write a program that accepts a list of 2d points and tries to find/approximate a steiner tree of minimal length connecting those points by possibly introducing more points. (It does not have to find the an actual steiner tree.)

The program should output a list of all the points (including coordinates) of the constructed graphs, a list of all edges (including their lengths), the total length of the graph and a graphical representation of the grap.

The program should have a running time of no more than about half a minute for each of the examples on a reasonable computer.

You should also explain how your algorithm works.

## Scoring

The program must be evaluated on all the [NOT YET] given test cases. The score is the sum of the total length of all test cases. The lowest score wins.

## Test cases

```
Square:
(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)

Nonagon:
(cos(2*pi*a/9),sin(2*pi*a/9)) for a = 0,1,...,8

Ladder:
(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),(4,0),(4,1),(5,0),(5,1)
```

## Meta: I need to find a good set of test cases. Suggestions are appreciated.

If you have any suggestions, feel free to edit/add. Any improvements of the text are appreciated too.

@El'endia Starman Pointed out some [interesting n-gon configurations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043910/what-would-a-steiner-tree-look-like-for-the-vertices-of-a-heptagon)

Comment: It is known that Steiner trees for regular n-gons where 7 <= n <= 12 are simply the n-gon with one side removed. 4,5,6 all have interesting configurations though.

Answer (score 3):

## Approximate phi using Fibonacci numbers

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci)

As shown by Johannes Kepler, the quotient of successive Fibonacci numbers approaches phi.

[image: Thanks, Wikipedia.]

(where F(n) = the nth Fibonacci number)

The fine folks at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients) also say that if you choose two different starting values for the Fibonacci sequence, this expression still holds.

Last, but not least, if you use a later number in the series in the numerator, you get some interesting properties:

[image: Thanks again, wikipedia]

### The challenge

- Create a full program or function that approximates phi using Fibonacci numbers.
- The program or function will take a single integer, n (unless a bonus is applied). It will output to STDOUT as follows, stopping when it reaches n:

`1/1=1
2/1=2
3/2=1.5
5/3=1.66666666
...
F(n+1)/F(n)=...`

- Fibonacci numbers must be calculated using iteration or recursion.
- No built-ins / standard loopholes, and neither the square root function nor phi should appear in the source code.
- It is OK if floating point limitation/integer overflow prevent accuracy beyond 4 or 5 digits, but you should use the most precise primitive data type (yes, double is one character longer than float).

There are two bonuses that you can earn, for a total of a 25% lower score:

- Input two additional integers as starting values for the Fibonacci sequence. This will still converge on phi, though it may take a bit longer. Reward: -10%.
- Input one additional integer for *a* in the above formula. This will result in the sequence converging to phi^a. Reward: -15%.

### Scoring

Total score is the size of the program, in bytes, minus any bonuses. Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score wins.

(Insert leaderboard snippet)
(Insert example snippet)

**Example implementation snippet:**

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", process, false);

function process() {
  //Store field values to vars
  var itrNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("itrNum").value);
  var prevNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("start1").value);
  var curNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("start2").value);
  var aNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("aVal").value);
  document.write("(Click \"Run\" to reset)<br><br>");

  //Iterate through each fibbonacci number
  for (var i = 0; i < itrNum; i++) {

    dispNum = getFutureItr(prevNum, curNum, aNum);
    document.write(dispNum + " / " + prevNum + " = " + dispNum / prevNum + "<br>");
    //prepare numbers for next iteration
    var tempNum = curNum + prevNum;
    prevNum = curNum;
    curNum = tempNum;
  }
}

//Helper function for F(n+a)
function getFutureItr(prevNum,
  curNum,
  aNum) {
  var tempNum = curNum;
  for (var i = 1; i < aNum; i++) {
    tempNum = curNum + prevNum;
    prevNum = curNum;
    curNum = tempNum;
  }
  return curNum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Iteration number:
  <input type="number" min=0 id="itrNum" value=20>
  <hr>Starting value 1:
  <input type="number" min=1 id="start1" value=1>
  <br>
  <br>Starting value 2:
  <input type="number" min=1 id="start2" value=1>
  <hr>Value of a:
  <input type="number" min=1 id="aVal" value=1>
  <hr>
  <button id="button">Calculate</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a [tag:fibonacci] tag. It's generally worth making it clear which of the two indexing conventions answers to use: `F(0) = 0` or `F(0) = 1`?

Comment: Does the output need to be in the exact format `3/2=1.5`?

Answer (score 3):

## Counting the Pattern Unlocks

**Meta**

*Upon thinking about this challenge harder, I've realized that it is fairly trivial. Unless I am really bad at counting (which I am liable to be), there are at least 2 ways and at most 4 ways to draw any given pattern.*

*I think that this makes the challenge considerably less attractive. For this reason, I am thinking of ways to spice it up. For this, I would like your feedback. Currently I am thinking of:*

-->Changing the rules so that dots can be used multiple times.

*Let me know what you think of this change to the challenge, or suggest other changes.*

**The Premise**

Many modern smartphones have options that allow you to choose how you would like to unlock your phone. For example, my phone allows

1. PIN input: a 4 digit number (low security)
2. Pattern Unlock: connect the dots in a pattern (medium security)
3. Password entry: enter a password (high security)
4. Fingerprint.

When you elect this second option, you are shown a 3x3 grid of dots (9 dots total) that looks something like this

```
.    .    .

.    .    .

.    .    .
```

Instead of using dots, we will use numbers in the following fashion for ease of reference.

```
1    2    3

4    5    6

7    8    9
```

You are then prompted to connect dots to form a pattern. This process is subject to the following rules:

1. The pattern must use at least 3 dots.
2. The pattern must be one continuous connection, that is once you lift your finger, the pattern ends.
3. Each dot may be used at most once (there is a quasi exception to this in rule 4)
4. If you take three collinear dots, in connecting the outer two dots, you must connect the inner dot if it is not already used. For example, if you make the connection 1-3, if 2 is not already used, you are really making the connection 1-2-3. If 2 is already used, then you are just making the connection 1-3. This is where the quasi exception to rule 3 comes in. You are passing over 2 again, even though you have already used it.

*I believe that these are all the rules. Note that some phones may use different rules, but if you think I am missing something important, please let me know*.

## The Task

**Our goal is to count how many ways there are to draw a given pattern.**

For example if you see the following pattern:

```
1----2----3

4    5    6

7    8    8
```

It could have been drawn in one of four ways:

```
1 --> 2 --> 3    or
3 --> 2 --> 1    or
2 --> 3 --> 1    or
2 --> 1 --> 3
```

**Input**

You will be given a series of integers between 1 and 9 to stdin. They will represent connected dots on a grid.

The above example could be input via any of the following sequences:

```
1 2 3    or
3 2 1    or
2 3 1    or
2 1 3    or
1 3      or
3 1
```

If input is invalid, your program may do whatever it wants.

**Output**

Your program is to output the number of ways there are to draw the pattern, as an ingeter, to stdout or equivalent. In the above example, the output would be

```
4
```

**Wining Criterion**

This is code golf, shortest code (bytes) wins.

**Bonus**

Take off 20% if your answer also outputs all ways to draw the pattern (any understandable syntax acceptable).

**TEST CASES**

(1) grid layout

```
1    2    3
        /
4    5    6
|  /
7    8    9
```

possible inputs:

```
input>> 4 7 3
     >> 4 7 5 3
     >> 3 7 4
     >> 3 5 7 4
     >> 5 3 7 4
output<< 3
```

the ways are (for the bonus):

```
4 --> 7 --> 5 --> 3    or
3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 4    or
5 --> 3 --> 7 --> 4
```

(2)

```
1----2----3
|
4    5----6
|         |
7----8----9

input>> 3 2 1 4 7 8 9 6 5    or
     >> 3 1 7 9 6 5          or
     >> 5 6 9 7 1 3          or
     a couple others
output<< 3
```

example directions:

```
 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 9 --> 6 --> 5   or
 5 --> 6 --> 9 --> 7 --> 1 --> 3   or
 2 --> 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 9 --> 6 --> 5
 (or could include extra collinear points)
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: you are correct. Counting is just really hard apparently. Fixed (I think).

Comment: I've done worse... This is what the sandbox is for :)

Comment: It's generally good advice to write an ungolfed reference implementation while sandboxing. This will help ensure test cases are consistent, and also will sometimes highlight potential problems/changes that none of us could spot without an implementation.

Comment: Nice challenge, by the way.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll work on an implementation

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35234/194) and [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25139/194). Might give you some ideas (or at least ensure that your claims about the pattern are consistent with theirs!)

Answer (score 3):

## Who is the Star Abuser?

In [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) some people often star chat messages without any reason. You decided to go on a quest to find out who is the star abuser.

You logged the chat actions as a string, each action represented by a character (as you are a code golfer after all).

- Every user is marked with a letter of the alphabet.
- An uppercase version marks the user entering chat and a lowercase one marks his/her leaving the chat.
- At the start there is no one at the chat room.
- A star marks a starring. We assume that each person in the chat could have starred with the same probability when a starring happened. (E.g. if there are 2 users in the chat we assume both of them had 50% chance to star.)

An example log:

```
MOA***a**oS**s*Cc
```

You should output one uppercase letter showing the letter of the user who has the highest number of expected starring. If there are multiple users, output exactly one of them.

### Input:

```
TODO
```

### Output:

```
TODO
```

### Examples:

```
TODO
```

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: As soon as you add IO and ping me. I will upvote this

Comment: Example : `MOA***a**oS**s*Cc` > `M`

Answer (score 3):

## Comedy of exceptions

Your goal is to demonstrate the shortest program or function that can throw 10 different types of errors/exceptions (I use the two interchangeably here) at runtime.

**This question is only open to languages which have an object-oriented type system for errors. Furthermore, in the case of each error, a message including a clear identification of the exception's type must be printed**. Evidently, it must also have at least 10 error types. Other systems such as an integer error code identifying the error, or all errors represented by strings are not acceptable.

Input is an integer from 0 to 9 inclusive. The program should reliably throw a different type of error for each input.

Methods which allow exceptions of arbitrary type to be thrown **may not be used**. E.g, `throw ...` .

#### Determining whether two errors are of different type (TODO: fill in detail of output)

Java: x and y print different stack traces, but are the same type, so they can't be used.

Python: UnboundLocalError ..... and NameError ....... would count as two types of error, since, although UnboundLocalError is a subclass of NameError, `type()` would give different results for the two.

C++: stoi("aaaa") printing ......... would be valid since the message gives `std::invalid_argument`. Integer division by zero would not since it crashes the program without a message informing of the error type

#### Sandbox

Please comment if you are aware of a language that is borderline on eligibility, blurs boundaries between error types, or has other loopholes.

Comment: Would exceptions from standard modules be allowed (e.g. `from urllib.error import *`)? How about third-party modules/libraries (e.g. django, boost)? Or even custom exception subclasses?

Comment: I don't know if I can find 10 different ones, but CJam can print a number of errors. Some of these are CJam-specific errors (empty stack, type mismatch; these tend to be displayed as "RuntimeException" but with a distinguishing error message) and some of them, I think, are just crashes happening in the interpreter exiting with a Java exception. How would that be treated? (I think it's also different between the Java and the JavaScript interpreter.)

Comment: To make this more specific, here are 11 different errors (with different error messages), but some are backed by the same exception type within the interpreter. Would these still count as different? http://pastebin.com/VJCiVYMf (Also note that CJam itself has no concept of exceptions... if there's an error it crashes... these are just the exceptions types used by the interpreter.)

Comment: I can think of a language which has exceptions but not an object-oriented type system: [SML](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/exceptions.htm). (Haskell almost certainly has some exception monad too...).

Comment: @grc I think I will allow standard libraries, but not 3rd-party ones. Any method of defining and throwing a custom exception type should fall under the rule "Methods which allow exceptions of arbitrary type to be thrown may not be used."

Comment: @MartinBüttner It appears that the are Java exceptions and that CJam does not have its own exception type system, meaning it cannot be used.

Comment: @PeterTaylor HM-based type systems should be OK. Maybe I can find a better description than "object-oriented".

Comment: @feersum Then you should probably clarify what you mean by "error" (because the first sentence says that both errors and exceptions are allowed... just because there's no way to catch the error doesn't mean that language doesn't have errors... and most of these errors are actually thrown by the interpreter on purpose, and not raised by Java due to the interpreter having a bug).

Comment: @sysreq The input is a number when determines which type of exception you should throw.

Answer (score 3):

### Juggling without collisions [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Determine if a [siteswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siteswap) juggling pattern is valid, meaning that no two balls land on the same beat. Fewest bytes wins.

**Input:** A non-empty list of positive integers.

**Output:** A consistent [Truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value for valid or [Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value for invalid.

---

[Siteswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siteswap) is a notation for juggling patterns. Dividing time into units called beats, a siteswap pattern says how high to throw the ball each beat, measured in beats that it's airborne until you catch it. For example, the pattern

```
4 2 3
```

says

- On the first beat `t=1`, throw the ball `4` beats high, so you catch it at `t=5`.
- On the second beat `t=2`, throw the ball `2` beats high, so you catch it at `t=4`.
- On the third beat `t=3`, throw the ball `3` beats high, so you catch it at `t=6`.

If we treat this pattern as a periodic sequence

```
... 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 ...
```

note that on every beat, you catch exactly one ball. But, in

```
 5 1 3 4 2 ...
```

the ball thrown for `5` beats at `t=1` and the ball thrown for `3` beats at `t=3` both come down at `t=6`, which we don't want (let's ignore that we have two hands). This happens whenever two numbers in the sequence have the same different as the number of beats between them, with the bigger on first. Note that this may happen across repetitions, like in `8 1 2`, where the marked balls collide at `*`.

```
 v             v *
 8 1 2 8 1 2 8 1 2 8 1 2 ...
```

---

TODO: Test cases.

Sandbox: Does the explanation make sense? Is it too long for the challenge?

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25178/8478) :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Those are some nice ASCII diagrams, mind if I steal them?

Comment: Sure, if you don't mind them blowing up your spec. ;)

Comment: I think this challenge should still be happening. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder I've had this in the sandbox way too long, and don't have the energy to polish it up now. Do you want to take it?

Answer (score 3):

## Rational Number to Repeating Numeral Conversion

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

As I'm sure you know, the decimal expansion of every rational number is either **terminating**—consisting of a finite number of digits, or **repeating**—consisting of infinitely many digits, but ending with a finite pattern that repeats itself indefinitely: for example, the decimal expansion of the rational number 1/6 is `0.1666...`, where the sixes repeat forever.
One way to represent this decimal expansion finitely and unambiguously, is to write the repeating part, called the **repetend**, enclosed in parentheses:
going back to the previous example, under this scheme the number 1/6 is written as `0.1(6)`.
We call this representation a **repeating decimal**.
Of course, none of this is specific to base 10.
More generally, we call such a representation, in any base, a **repeating numeral**.
Note that, for the sake of this challenge, we use the term "repeating numeral" (or simply, "numeral") to refer to any numeral written using this scheme, whether or not it actually has a repeating part.

### Challenge

Write a **program** or a **function** taking a pair of integers, ***p*** and ***q***, and returning a repeating numeral representing the rational number *p*/*q*.
You may assume that *p* ≥ 0, and *q* > 0, so that *p*/*q* is never negative.
The resulting numeral should be in **base 10**, unless you go for the relevant bonus below.

There is more than one possible numeral representing a given rational number.
For example, the rational number 1/1 can be represented, among (infinitely many) other options, as `1`, `1.0`, `1.(0)`, `0.(9)`, and so on...
For this challenge, however, we'd like the output to be unique.
The following set of rules, which your program must follow, takes care of that:

- When the integer part of the numeral is zero, there should be a single `0` before the radix point.
  For example, given the input 1/2, the output should be `0.5`, and not `.5`.
- The repetend, if exists, must begin after the radix point; that is, it shouldn't apply to the integer part.
  For example, given the input 10/9, the output should be `1.(1)`, and not `(1)`.
- The output should be finite and minimal, under the above rules.
  This is the most significant rule controlling the output, so it's worth highlighting some of its consequences:

  - There should be no leading or trailing zeroes.
    For example, given the input 3/2, the output should be `1.5`, and not `01.5` or `1.50`.
  - If the fractional part is zero, it should be omitted.
    For example, given the input 1/1, the output should be `1`, and not `1.0`.
  - If the repetend is zero, it should be omitted.
    For example, given the input 1/2, the output should be `0.5`, and not `0.5(0)`.
  - When the input admits a terminating numeral, there shouldn't be an unnecessary repetend.
    For example, given the input 1/1, the output should be `1`, and not `0.(9)`.
  - The repetend, and the rest of the fractional part, should not be superfluous; there shouldn't be any repetition in the repetend itself, nor in the repetend and the rest of the fractional part.
    For example, given the input 1/99, the output should be `0.(01)`, and not `0.01(01)`, `0.(0101)`, or `0.0(10)`.

As usual, you may not use any **built-in or library functions** aimed specifically at this problem.

### Input and Output

You may take the **input** through the **command line**, through **STDIN**, as **function arguments**, or using an **equivalent method**.
You may use **any convenient format** for the input, but make sure to specify it in your post.
You may assume that *p* and *q* are no greater than 10,000,000, to the extent that it helps you to avoid overflow.

You may write the **output** to **STDOUT**, return it as the **function's result** or through an **output parameter**, **as a string**, or use an **equivalent method**.

### Score

This is **code-golf**. The **shortest answer**, in bytes, combined with the any of the **bonuses**, wins.

### Bonuses

If, in addition to the requirements listed above, your program satisfies the requirements for any of the following bonuses, **multiply** your score by the specified amount.

**×0.8 Bonus Support other bases**

Your program should take a third parameter, ***b***, which is an integer between 2 and 36, inclusive, and return the corresponding numeral in base *b*, instead of base 10.
The letters of the alphabet, either in lowercase or uppercase, should be used as digits above 9.
For example, given the input 1/2 and *b*=3, the output should be `0.(1)`.
Note that base *b* applies only to the *output*—if your program takes its input in string form, it should interpret it in base 10.

**×0.6 Bonus *O*(1) space complexity**

Your program's space complexity should be *O*(1), where the unit of space is the amount of space required to hold the input.
In other words, the amount of memory required by your program should, on a large scale, be proportional to the amount of memory required by the input.
You may not use the fact that the input range is bounded when reasoning about your program's space complexity, other than to the extent of establishing the amount of space required by the input.
If you go for this bonus, it is *strongly advised* that you include at least a brief explanation of your program, so that others can verify that it meets the criterion.

If your program does not print the output directly, but rather returns a string, you may ignore the space occupied by the string as long as your program only appends to the string, and doesn't modify or read from it otherwise.
(Note that something like `s=s+"0"` is fine, even though it technically involves reading from the string.)

### Test Cases

Each of the test cases below lists the input, `p/q`, on the first line, and the corresponding output on the second line.
Some of the tests list a third parameter, `b`, which specifies a different base for the output.
These tests are only applicable for the relevant bonus.

**Short-Output Tests**

Your program should solve each of the following tests in a matter of **seconds**.

```
0/1
0

123/123
1

12/3
4

1/2
0.5

1/3
0.(3)

7/6
1.1(6)

3/11
0.(27)

1234/9999
0.(1234)

7/12
0.58(3)

22/7
3.(142857)

123/456
0.269(736842105263157894)

7124771/4545450
1.56(745118)

1/68
0.01(4705882352941176)

678/2345
0.2(891257995735607675906183368869936034115138592750533049040511727078)

7683/238
32.2(815126050420168067226890756302521008403361344537)

123631/99999
1.(23632)

4576/2345
1.9(513859275053304904051172707889125799573560767590618336886993603411)

2239231/4950000
0.45236(98)

673/23430
0.0(2872385830132309005548442168160478019632949210413999146393512590695689)

8984/2318
3.(875754961173425366695427092320966350301984469370146678170836928386540120793787748058671268334771354616048317515099223468507333908541846419327006039689387402933563416738567730802415)

1/2 2
0.1

214/5467 13
0.(067ccb5145334200a07b6253394bc5ca12bc650017b87998acc2c516a7993810702ba1)

214 5467 11
0.0(481119a34a86245a0053a1022114643a64131367585a8095498942556925833303993816590371976aa2a6952238969a61490900a792044229187a18262724060a517a986785002750566607877532070733842a95a27a4476828a12971701a4740884573649355153)

330420/335923 36
0.(zero)

9322181/306936 28
12.ab(cd)

123/6573 29
0.(0flb8c3hblol)

123/6573 21
0.0(85669592cjj9ca173fij6g67hhg7g940b5efk6j2bb7276c1ch25ikf7dd070jf4h96hek41ji102h3ea6kb2ic5hc3089b19kjc8dfhaf9147c48kgg4k5ab463d1fd5k86eigacciai54ihj3k2e7aghdbcfeebfbi811b8ajdh521e4ed334d4bgk9f650e1i99dide8j83if205d77kdk15g3be360gj12jki3h6ae09i28f38hkcb9jb018c753a5bjgd8gc044g0fa9geh7j57f0ce624a882a2fg231h0i6da4379)
```

**Long-Output Tests**

The following tests produce significantly longer output.
Instead of listing their full output, only the MD5 checksum of the output if given.
The checksum is calculated without a trailing newline, and using lowercase letters for digits above 9 (in the relevant test cases).
If you want to see the full output for these tests, or to calculate the checksum under different conditions, you can use the test snippet below.
Your program should solve each of the following tests in no more than a few **minutes**.

```
343/677472
e1810c85500a97c36f2ba5dcc94a2aa6

234/62332
662adcee10cd77d001282f0e31a84b77

57628/7894211
81222aaa93f192c6d8334fcde6381a74

67332/1267232
3ea190c83a735a8bafc922cbb177e6f4

954/3684332
d4ef940c9986f9c2ac52ee822d94d6a7

783232/3462241
7724d3444b5540b8b4f07d13317e8da3

83/7657124
b295369267f48e642e202e0364898c82

764231/54646224
ecf7f3dd12f2d495b31a178fc03662d7

6743/1231234
9f447fd27447abb881795fc5e2f814e5

764/9343249
8381dc6f127be6d95cadc0b5bdd70104

345/2234448 22
667d437e35c3825696f64f1b27e6a827

63451/2343324 3
5d86d77856cc0a15ac8a51b46c2f22d6

93457/546464 2
1084e884aded53f0da933480c45db1b8

678541/453524 9
5bb54bddaab7bd933258d4d78a83cdba

4572/2341198 15
39af2bc67ab58438068f672ed3a8357d

1/4821466 6
57ba79a48c438b7fd21aa39ee3575c8d

145/5821417 21
009f087ae661cfd4690cc51ba71a827f

5472/2333645 33
d24583dfdad205de61763c6a87637979
```

### Test Snippet

If you want to further test your submission, you can use the following test snippet to find the repeating numeral representation of arbitrary rational numbers, or to find the rational number corresponding to arbitrary repeating numerals.
Note that the result can get very big, very fast, which can be a little much for your browser; in this case, you might want to uncheck the "Result" checkbox, and check the "MD5" checkbox, to only get the MD5 checksum of the output.
Note also that you can resize the input and output boxes.

```html
<style>* { font-family: sans-serif; }table { border-collapse: collapse; }table > tbody > tr > td { padding: 0px; }#status { display: none; }#status[loading] { display: initial; font-style: italic; }#main { display: none; width:100%; border-right:.7em solid transparent; font-size: 95%; }#main[loaded] { display: table; }#main > tbody > tr + tr > td { padding-top: .25em; }#main > tbody > tr > td + td { padding-left: .5em; }#main > tbody > tr > td:first-of-type { width: 4.25em; }.label { white-space: pre; }#flags { padding-left: 2.4em; font-size: smaller; }#flags > table > tbody > tr > td + td { padding-left: 1em; }#error { display: none; font-size: smaller; color: #880000; }#error[error] { display: initial; }#job_cancel, #job_throbber { display: none; vertical-align: bottom; }#job_cancel[working], #job_throbber[working] { display: initial; }#job_throbber > img { height: 1em; }#job_throbber[working] { padding-left: .3em; }#job_cancel[working] { padding-left: 1em; }#job_cancel > input { height: 1.8em; font-size: small; }input[type="text"], input[type="number"], textarea { padding: 0.25em; height: 1.4em; font-family: monospace; }textarea { width: 100%; }#base { width: 2.8em; text-align: right; }.output { background-color: #e4e4e4; border: none; }#length { width: 8em; text-align: right; }#md5 { width: 20em; text-align: center; }#result_container[active="false"] { display: none; }#md5_container[active="false"] { display: none; }</style></head><body><div id="status" loading>Loading...</div><table id="main" onkeydown="handle_key_down(event)"><tr><td id="input_label" class="label">Fraction:</td><td><textarea id="input" oninput="update(true)" spellcheck="false">123/456</textarea></td></tr><tr><td class="label">Base:</td><td><table><tr><td><input id="base" type="number" value="10" spellcheck="false" oninput="update(true)"></td><td id="flags"><table><tr><td><label><table><tr><td><input id="flag_result" type="checkbox" checked onchange="handle_flag('result')"></td><td>Result</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label><table><tr><td><input id="flag_md5" type="checkbox" onchange="handle_flag('md5')"></td><td>MD5</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label><table><tr><td><input id="flag_uppercase" type="checkbox" onchange="handle_flag('uppercase')"></td><td>Uppercase</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label><table><tr><td><input id="flag_trailing_newline" type="checkbox" onchange="handle_flag('trailing_newline')"></td><td>Trailing Newline</td></tr></table></label></td><td><label><table><tr><td><input id="flag_progressive_output" type="checkbox" onchange="handle_flag('progressive_output')"></td><td>Progressive Output</td></tr></table></label></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><span id="error"></span></td></tr><tr><td class="label">Length:</td><td><table id="length_table"><tr><td><input id="length" class="output" type="text" spellcheck="false" readonly></td><td id="job_throbber"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHKZY.gif"></td><td id="job_cancel"><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel_job()"><td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id="md5_container"><td class="label">MD5:</td><td><input id="md5" class="output" type="text" spellcheck="false" readonly></td></tr><tr id="result_container"><td id="result_label" class="label">Numeral:</td><td class="full_width"><textarea id="result" class="output" spellcheck="false" readonly></textarea></td></tr></table><script async type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.githack.com/anonymous/49705525fd01ba66c1ad/raw/c35226ad89444e3af07d0e505f7163df8574b860/repnum.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't space complexity technically going to be at least O(log (p+q))?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Technically, yes. I'm going to define the unit of space as the amount of space required to hold the input, thus implicitly dividing by O(log n).

Comment: Ah, that's a very good idea. Much better than the usual attempts of "but ignore the memory used to store the input...".

Comment: I completely ignored your actual question: no, I wouldn't consider it a duplicate. ;)

Comment: I like the simplicity of the idea and would suggest keeping it simple by not requiring other bases or having a complexity limit.

Comment: I agree with @xnor; I also think the bonuses are unnecessary.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Keep in mind that xnor's comment was written before the actual spec, when the bonuses were proposed as hard requirements (see the edit history.) I'm not likely to get rid of the O(1) space thing entirely—I think it makes for a much more interesting challenge (there's also a closely related challenge [edit history] that I don't want to get too close to.) TBH, I think the different bases bonus is mostly interesting in conjunction with the O(1) space bonus; I agree that in itself it doesn't add too much to the challenge.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the bonuses. Also, I'm concerned there will be disagreements about the space complexity of built-ins. In some languages, implementation is not apecified, only result. It's also hard to tell n log n from linear because of constants.

Comment: @xnor I'm going to go with common sense with regard to builtins: If the most obvious implementation of a builtin is O(1), then, unless someone knows otherwise, I'm fine with it. If the builtin does something nontrivial, that might not be O(1), then it's the poster's responsibility to show it's O(1), or not use it. I agree that reasoning about complexity is tricky, and complicates things: that's part of the challenge, and that's why I think it deserves a bonus.

Comment: The space complexity required to hold the input is O(n), not O(1), since n is conventionally the input length, and O(1) is a constant that does not depend on the input.

Comment: @xnor We can use whatever "frame of reference" we want when measuring complexity. If we define the unit of space to be the amount of space required by the input, then a complexity of O(1) simply means that space usage has to be proportional to the space occupied by the input, which might (in "absolute" terms) be fixed, or might depend on the actual value of _p_ and _q_. Specifying it this way allows us to define the complexity requirement uniformly, without worrying about the details.

Comment: @xnor, ThomasKwa, Anyway, having thought about it some more, I might end up dropping the bonuses, and doing the complexity thing out-of-band as a bounty. I'm going to leave this in the sandbox for a while longer, at least until next year... Happy new year!

Comment: No, that's like saying we define 2 to be 3 and then 2+2=6. O(1) means O(1). 1 is not a variable. Readers will get confused if you redefine existing notation.

Comment: How if my program allocates p+q+n space with n constant and unit space is byte?

Comment: Make all bonus mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

## Elements with 100 ≤ Z < 1000

---

The International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC) decided that it is necessary to have a systematic naming for the elements, even for those which had not been discovered. The rules for naming are:

1. The name is derived directly from the atomic number of the element using the following Latin numerical roots:

   ```
   Number     Root
   ------     ----
   0          nil
   1          un
   2          bi
   3          tri
   4          quad
   5          pent
   6          hex
   7          sept
   8          oct
   9          enn
   ```
2. The roots are put together in the order of the digits which make up the atomic number and terminated by `'ium'` to spell out the name. The final `'n'` of `'enn'` is omitted when it occurs before `'nil'`, and the final `'i'` of `'bi'` and of `'tri'` when it occurs before `'ium'`.
3. The symbol of the element is composed of the initial letters of the numerical roots which make up the name.

**For this challenge, let us consider the elements having a three digit atomic number.**

Examples:

```
100 --> Unnilnilium
101 --> Unnilunium
111 --> Unununium
150 --> Unpentnilium
200 --> Binilnilium
500 --> Pentnilnilium
999 --> Ennennennium
```

## Input

- Input can be taken from one of the following

  - `stdin`
  - Command-line arguments
  - Function arguments (One argument, as a string)
- Input will contain either a valid IUPAC name of an element, or a valid IUPAC symbol of an element.

## Output

- Output the corresponding

  - IUPAC name if the input is a symbol of an element.
  - symbol if the input is an IUPAC name of an element.

## Rules

- The input will contain a **valid** IUPAC name/symbol.
- The first character of the symbol/name in input will be in upper-case and should remain capitalized in the output.
- You are permitted to write a full program or a function.
- There should be no unnecessary characters except an optional trailing newline character.

## Test Cases

```
Unu            --> Unnilunium
Eee            --> Ennennennium
Enn            --> Ennilnilium
Bnb            --> Binilbium
Ubt            --> Unbitrium
Qsn            --> Quadseptnilium

Septenntrium   --> Set
Hexunbium      --> Hub
Octennilium    --> Oen
Bibibium       --> Bbb
Ununennium     --> Uue
Triquadpentium --> Tqp
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

---

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

---

*Sandbox*: What do you guys think about this challenge? Anything to improve? Did I miss anything?

Comment: For the title, maybe "Elements after Fermium", since that's element 100.

Comment: Omit the line "not relevant in this challenge"

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60208/element-names-above-118

Comment: @ThomasKwa Oh. Thanks! Didn't know that a similar challenge existed!

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I made some changes now.

Answer (score 3):

[This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68185/write-the-new-vim) was closed, because it was way too broad, but, in the comments, SuperJedi224 suggested a slightly different challenge that I thought was a really good idea, so I'm stealing it and posting it here.

---

## Write a text editor in 2000 bytes or less

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Write a text editor in 2000 bytes or less. It should support loading and saving files (or something else if your language doesn't support that, maybe?), modifying text, and displaying the contents of a file that's currently open in some format.

### Sandbox questions

- I'm not sure if 2000 bytes is the right number. SuperJedi224 originally suggested 10000, but that seems to me like too many.
- Should some features be required, or should it just be by votes? Will votes take care of possible submissions that aren't actually text editors?
- <s>Should there be some kind of bonus for shorter submissions? Maybe an extra point for every 20 or so bytes you don't use?</s> No, there probably shouldn't be.
- Should languages that don't support file operations be allowed?

Comment: This is still very broad, and I think I would vote to close as off-topic, as this is essentially a UX contest, which isn't much different from an art contest.

Comment: I would recommend either an upper limit on bytes, or plain code golf. Trying to be somewhere in between with a bonus seems awkward.

Comment: @trichoplax I agree. Plain code golf won't work unless we can create a much more precise specification, and that doesn't seem as interesting as a popularity contest, so I guess it should just be an upper limit.

Comment: I think that the more precise you make the requirements, the more the voting can reflect how well the code fulfills these, rather than just being about arbitrary popularity. The more open ended the popularity criteria, the more likely the question will be closed.

Comment: That's a good point. Do you have any suggestions for criteria?

Comment: Whatever limit you choose, there will be some languages which are excluded by this and other languages for which the limit is too high to provide any restriction. So instead of trying to suit all languages, it might be easiest to just think about the readers of the answers - how much code do you want them to have to read through for each answer?

Comment: I guess you can add criteria gradually while it's here in the sandbox until it seems ready. What's the bare minimum it should be able to do? Do you just want keyboard input or mouse input too? Are there any shortcuts that should be included?

Comment: Not sure if this will be relevant, but just as a rough guide, [this list of small text editors](http://www.texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?TinyEditors) includes Emacs in 2000 lines of C. I'm guessing 2000 bytes will be more than enough for a very basic text editor in most languages.

Comment: I recommend doing this as a [tag:code-golf] challenge, an upper limit just discourages the use languages where you are not sure whether you make it under that limit. Then also please make precise requirements, my suggestion: accept filename via stdin, file should contain printable ascii characters only, display blinking(or static) cursor, display should have a certain width (given number of characters) and enforces line breaks if the lines are longer, navigation via arrows, enable backspace (and if you want delete)

Answer (score 3):

## Addition of doubles... without doubles [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [golf-cpu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golf-cpu)

For this challenge, you must write a [*GOLF*](https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu) assembly program that takes two [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) double-precision numbers and returns their sum.

#### The Format

IEEE 754 doubles use 8 bytes to store a floating-point value. The memory is laid out like this:

[image] <sub>*([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IEEE_754_Double_Floating_Point_Format.svg))*</sub>

For the purposes of this challenge, all numbers will be in big-endian, and you won't have to worry about overflows or underflows. Addition works roughly like this (I won't go into all of the details):

1. Align the two numbers to a common exponent.
2. Add the fractional parts, taking into account the sign.
3. If the addition overflows, then change the exponent to match.

#### I/O

Your program will receive 16 bytes of input. The first 8 represent the (big-endian) first number, and the rest represent the second number. Your program will return 8 bytes representing the sum of the two.

#### Rules

- This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the program that completes the task with the least cycles wins.
- The score of an answer is the mean number of cycles required for adding uniformly distributed numbers in [-10^64, 10^64].
- You must test with at least 2500 trials.
- Your code doesn't have to handle infinities/NaNs.
- **Your *GOLF* binary (after assembling) must fit in 4096 bytes.**

### Meta Questions

- Do I have too many/too few trials?
- Is there something that I overlooked?
- Is there a more fitting title?
- How much explanation should I provide? I don't want this question to turn into a Wikipedia article, but questions requiring external resources are generally frowned upon.
- Is [colf-cpu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colf-cpu) dead?

Answer (score 3):

## Play Flippy Bit

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [pathfinding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinding)

There's a simple [game](http://flippybitandtheattackofthehexadecimalsfrombase16.com/) called "Flippy Bit and the Attack of the Hexadecimals from Base 16", originally made as an April Fool's prank in 2014.

The premise is simple: Enemies enter the field from the top. Each one has a hexadecimal number, and are destroyed when the player's binary number matches. For example, an enemy with number `2Ah = 00101010b` would be destroyed as soon as the user's number is `00101010`. Of course, enemies can only be destroyed after they enter the screen.

The player manipulates their binary number by flipping individual bits with the `qwertyui` keys, where `q` is the most significant bit. Each press flips the bit at that location. Therefore, the `2A` enemy above will explode if, starting from 0, the player presses `etu` in any order. When an enemy explodes, the player's number is reset to `0`.

### Challenge

Given a list of enemies, determine a sequence of keypresses that can destroy all enemies in the order given. This isn't as simple as it seems: if you're trying to destroy `3` but there's another enemy called `2` on the board, you'll need to press `i` before `u`. Your algorithm must terminate within a bounded time.

#### Input

A list of strings of hex digits `0123456789ABCDEF`, with each string 1 or 2 digits long, and where the 2-digit strings have no leading zero. You may also take the input in a reasonable format other than a list; for example, newline-separated. The input will always represent a solvable configuration.

#### Output

A string representing the sequence of keypresses.

#### Test cases

Note that there are multiple possible outputs for most inputs.

```
2A 01 02 04 08 10 20 40 A0 88
quetqwertyui
```

[add more test cases]

Verify your solutions with the following Python:

```
[add verification code]
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: This may or may not be an excuse to award a bounty to the highest Flippy Bit score.

Comment: I had no idea that the `qwertyui` keys would flip the bits. This would actually make kind of a cool esoteric language, however.

Comment: The statement that "*destroy[ing] all enemies in order ... isn't as simple as it seems*" puzzled me for a while, because I couldn't see what was wrong with the simple approach of setting the bits from the least significant to the most significant. Having thought about it, I presume that what's missing is a statement that the order in question is the order in which the enemies are presented in the input. But then an input like `03 01 02` is impossible to solve, so you also need to address insoluble inputs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually, it's not! `quiq`. The point of this is some sort of search.

Comment: `ff 01 02 04 08 10 20 40 80` then. (Although I see you've addressed the issue, so this comment is only for completeness).

Answer (score 3):

## HTML Obfuscation

Write a program or function that takes HTML as a string as input and outputs "obfuscated" HTML.  Leave the text between the `<`s and `>`s unchanged, but escape all other text.

- You can assume that the `<` and `>` characters will only be used to open/close HTML tags.
- You can safely leave any text between these characters alone.  However, any text not between those characters should take on the form `<ampersand><pound><ascii-encoding><semi-colon>`.
- You do NOT have to support self closing tags.

### Test cases:

Input:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;</div>
```

Input:

```
ABC<input type="text">DEF<div>
```

Output:

```
&#65;&#66;&#67;<input type="text">&#68;&#69;&#70;<div>
```

Note: it's ok that the HTML is invalid

Input:

```
eee<div data-bracket=">">eee
```

Output:

```
&#101;&#101;&#101;<div data-bracket=">&#34;&#62;&#101;&#101;&#101;
```

Note: here your program would mess up the HTML.  That's ok for the purposes of the challenge.

This is code golf, so the shortest program wins.

Comment: I think you should be more specific about what exact subset of HTML needs to be handled correctly (and include test cases that cover all of it).

Comment: @MartinBüttner thanks for the feedback.  Do you think the edits clarify the challenge?

Comment: Basically: take a character and return the hexadecimal HTML entity.

Answer (score 3):

## Radiation-Protected Expressions

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

#### Challenge

Write a program, taking an integer n as input from -999,999 to 999,999 inclusive, that returns a string representing a valid expression evaluating to that number in your language.
The catch: this expression must NOT evaluate to any other number when evaluated if any single character is removed from it.

#### Restrictions

Your program must be <= 1024 bytes in length.

The outputted expressions must be in the same language as the generating program.

#### Scoring

Your score is the number of bytes in the largest string generated by your program for the entire range of valid numbers. Tiebreakers go to shortest code.

#### Examples of Valid Outputs *(in JavaScript)*

- `Math.PI|0||3` for n=3, because:

  - `ath.PI|0||3`, `Mth.PI|0||3`, `Mah.PI|0||3`, and `Mat.PI|0||3` cause ReferenceErrors,
  - `MathPI|0||3` causes a ReferenceError,
  - `Math.P|0||3`, `Math.I|0||3`, and `Math.PI0||3` result in 3,
  - `Math.PI|||3` causes a SyntaxError,
  - `Math.PI|0|3` results in 3, and
  - `Math.PI|0||` causes a SyntaxError.

- `9*(8)` is valid for n=72
- `(n=9e5)>96?n:9e5` for n=900,000
- `1` for n=1

  ---

#### Examples of Invalid Outputs *(in JavaScript)*

- `1e2` for n=100 because `12` is a valid expression that evaluates to a number other than 100.

Comment: "cause an error or continue to evaluate".  Those are two very different things, I'd say to just pick that the expression should continue to evaluate

Comment: @Downgoat My intent was that the expression could do anything except evaluate to a different number in the range. I thought it would make the challenge more approachable in different languages to allow errors.

Comment: I get `0` for `Math.P|0`.

Comment: @feersum Whoops, typed this too quickly. Fixed

Comment: For a lot of languages this probably boils down to one or two special cases and the rest of them are `max(expr,expr)` for numbers greater than 9, `min(expr,expr)` for numbers less than 0. So it's borderline dupe of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33077/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor True. Didn't think of that approach. In this case there would be incentive to golf the code to only employ the strategies necessary to achieve the minimal score, so it's not a complete dupe, but I'm not sure that the challenge in its current form is as interesting as I initially thought...

Answer (score 3):

## Capture the Flag

<sup>Do you ever wonder why we're here?</sup>

### Objective

Capture the enemy team's flag and return it to your base. The first team to 3 captures wins the round. The player with the most wins across all (number TBD) rounds wins the game.

### Teams

There will be two teams each round. Teams will be randomly, evenly assigned to all submissions at the start of each round.

### Playing

The game will be turn-based. At the start of each turn, each player will be given the current map. All players will move simultaneously. Players shall submit their move as a one or two character ASCII string, composed from the following options:

- First character: `w`ait, `m`ove, `s`tab (if not holding flag), `d`rop (if holding flag), or `p`ick-up (if standing on a flag)
- Second character: `n`orth, `e`ast, `s`outh, or `w`est, or nothing if `w`aiting, `d`ropping, or `p`icking-up

Moving a direction will result in the player moving one square in that direction if possible, otherwise standing still (for example, if the player is attempting to move into a wall, or into an occupied square). Stabbing in a direction will result in killing the player standing in the adjacent square in that direction, unless the player is a teammate (no teamkilling). Stabs are processed before moves each turn. Dropping the flag results in it being placed on the ground beneath the player. Drop, pick-up, and wait commands ignore the second character. Invalid commands are interpreted as waiting. Case is ignored, so `W` and `w` are the same command. Either team may pick up either flag.

If two or more players attempt to move onto the same square, one of the players will be randomly selected to successfully move, and the rest will not move.

If a player is killed, they will drop the flag they are holding (if they are holding one), and will respawn in 3 turns in an unoccupied square in their home base. If there is no unoccupied square in their home base, they will respawn in the nearest square to the base. Respawns happen after stabs, but before moves.

Inside each base, there will be a 5x5 square room, with doorways in the middle of each wall, and the team's flag in the center of the room. Players who spend 5 consecutive turns inside their team's flag room (this includes the 4 doorways), while no enemies are present in the flag room and they are not holding a flag, will be killed at the conclusion of the 5th turn, to discourage camping. Successfully placing the enemy's flag on top of your flag's stand (in the center of the room), either by `d`ropping it or being killed on top of the flag stand, will result in a point being scored for your team and the enemy's flag immediately returning to their flag stand.

### The Map

(work in progress)

The world map will be a single level (no upstairs or downstairs), represented as such:

```
# : wall, cannot be moved into
. : an empty space
F : the enemy team's flag
f : your flag
! : a flag stand (with no flag on it)
@ : you
$ : you, carrying the enemy flag
% : you, carrying your flag
p : one of your teammates
P : an enemy player
c : a teammate, carrying or standing on top of the enemy flag
C : an enemy player, carrying or standing on top of your flag
s : a teammate, carrying or standing on top of your flag
S : an enemy player, carrying or standing on top of the enemy flag
```

Here is an example map (the actual maps used in the tournament will be posted later):

```
####################################################
#..................................................#
#..###.###########.######........###......##########
#..#....................#..........................#
#..#.....###.###...................#######.........#
#..#.....#.....#........#..........................#
#..#.....#.....#........#...................#...#..#
#..#........f...........#..........................#
#........#.....#........#....#########.............#
#..#.....#.....#........#..........................#
#..#.....###.###........#......##################..#
#..#...............................................#
#..#.#################.............................#
#.........................###########.........###..#
#..................................................#
####################################...............#
####################################...............#
#..................................................#
#..................................................#
#...............####################################
#...............####################################
#..................................................#
#..###.........###########.........................#
#.............................#################.#..#
#...............................................#..#
#..##################......#........###.###.....#..#
#..........................#........#.....#.....#..#
#.............#########....#........#.....#........#
#..........................#...........F........#..#
#..#...#...................#........#.....#.....#..#
#..........................#........#.....#.....#..#
#.........#######...................###.###.....#..#
#..........................#....................#..#
##########......###........######.###########.###..#
#..................................................#
####################################################
```

### Controller

The controller and an example map and player are located [on the challenge's GitHub project](https://github.com/Mego/PyCTF). Once I finish the controller, I'll copy the program here.

### Restrictions

- Bots must be fully deterministic. RNGs may not be used.
- Bots may be written in any language, so long as they support reading ASCII input from STDIN and writing ASCII output to STDOUT. Anything that is written to STDERR will be ignored.
- Bots' processes will be started at the beginning of each turn, and must output their command and terminate within the given 5 seconds.
- Each bot will be able to store up to 1 MiB (1024*1024 bytes) of data on disk per game, for saving any stateful data they desire. The name of the bot's data file will be passed as the first command line argument to the bot process. Should a bot write more than 1 MiB of data during a single game, data from the beginning of the file will be removed to append additional data to the end of the file. At the end of each game, the data files will be wiped.
- Any attempt to tinker with the controller, runtime or other submissions will be disqualified. All submissions should only work with the inputs and storage they are given.
- Bots should not be written to beat or support specific other bots.

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

### Sandbox notes

Anything missing or unclear (other than the parts specifically marked as TBD)?

Comment: 1. The rules make most sense if turns are sequential rather than simultaneous, but it's nowhere stated which is the case. Simultaneous moves are fairer, but make the rules more complicated. Sequential moves make the assessment of what to do more complicated, because unless you track a lot of state from last time you don't know who's already moved. 2. Respawning in an unoccupied square requires there to be an occupied square. What if there isn't? 3. What stops camping just outside the door, in such a way that no-one can pass?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've addressed all 3 of these points in the latest edit.

Comment: No RNG? :( That's not as much fun.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Trust me, you'll be glad for that. Nobody wants a Caboose on their team.

Comment: So they can't stab themselves or take their own flag?

Comment: @RikerW Correct on the stabbing bit. I can't imagine why a player would want to stab themselves, though. Either team can pick up either flag; I need to fix that.

Comment: @Mego Every heard of EmoWolf? >.<

Comment: @RikerW That is exactly why suicides are not allowed. A rule is not needed, because that's a standard loophole.

Comment: You should make a rule that submissions can't lose on purpose by sacrificing their own flag

Comment: You never define what a "base" is. Is it half of the board?

Answer (score 3):

## Output the points of this twisting fractal

## Challenge

Output the points (in order) for the following fractal of size `n`:

[image: Size 4 example]

(The above example is for `n = 4`)

We begin with the [Binary Sierpinski Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67497/compute-the-binary-sierpinski-triangle-sequence), which can be generated recursively, by a number of cellular automata (including Rule 90), and by Pascal's Triangle.

As a refresher, Pascal's triangle is:

```
   |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7| 
---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
 0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|
 1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0| 
 2 |  1 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|
 3 |  1 |  3 |  3 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|
 4 |  1 |  4 |  6 |  4 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0|
 5 |  1 |  5 | 10 | 10 |  5 |  1 |  0 |  0|
 6 |  1 |  6 | 15 | 20 | 15 |  6 |  1 |  0|
 7 |  1 |  7 | 21 | 35 | 35 | 21 |  7 |  1|
```

Here rows are `i`, columns are `j`, and the values are `i choose j`.

Using Pascal's triangle, we replace each value with its remainder `mod 2` to get:

```
   |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7| 
---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
 0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|     O        
 1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|     OO       
 2 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|     O O      
 3 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0|     OOOO     
 4 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0|     O   O    
 5 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0|     OO  OO   
 6 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0|     O O O O  
 7 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1|     OOOOOOOO
```

With the result "plotted" to the right, the `n = 1` iteration of the Sierpinski Triangle.

Now, to keep the "centers" well defined, we take the center of each triangle to be its NE corner like so:

```
'              ^
''             |
'*'            N 
''''       <--E W-->
'  *'          S
''  ''         |
'*' '*'        v
''''''''
```

Here is pseudocode to generate the fractal:

```
fractal(n):
    position = nth center
    while SE possible:
        go SE
        mark position
    while not all full:
        if current level not full:
            rotate counterclockwise on current level
            mark position
        else:
            go NW until reach non-full level
            rotate counterclockwise on current level
            while SE possible:
                mark position
                go SE
    return marked positions
```

Here's what that looks like for `n = 2`:

```
 '                              
 ' '                            
 ' 12'                          
 ' ' ' '                        
 '      9'                      
 ' '     ' '                    
 ' 10'   ' 11'                  
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '                
 '               '              
 ' '             ' '            
 '  4'           '  8'          
 ' ' ' '         ' ' ' '        
 '      1'       '      5'      
 ' '     ' '     ' '     ' '    
 '  2'   '  3'   '  6'   '  7'  
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
```

Giving the following points marked (in order):

```
[[3, 12], [1, 14], [5, 14], [1, 10], [11, 12], [9, 14], [13, 14], [9, 10], [3, 4], [1, 6], [5,6], [1,2]]
```

## Rules

- Entry may be either a function or full program.
- Input is a non-negative integer.
- Output is the (properly ordered) list of points for the fractal above.
- You may use something other than a list to output the results if it allows the easy reading of the points, in order. For example, newline separated is fine.
- Output must contain exactly `(3^n - 3)/2` points.
- This is code golf so shortest wins!

## Questions

- Is everything well defined?
- Should I reformat the ASCII triangles? Or even replace everything with images?

Test cases if anyone is interested or I post this.

This is a challenge that I enjoyed solving so I hope I can smooth out the corners relatively quickly.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: I don't quite understand what the diagram with the `'` and `*` represents. Would it be possible to explain the construction without having to read pseudocode?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I believe so. I considered making a better animation but hoped it would be clear without one. The options I see are: animation, representative list of steps, or general improvement/refactoring of what I have so far. What do you think?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66875/help-im-trapped-in-a-sierpinski-triangle

Comment: I've been playing with this one recently, have a gif: https://gifyu.com/image/pumE

Answer (score 3):

## Replace magic numbers

Tags: [code-gold](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-gold) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Introduction

[Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) are a common problem in software development, since they tend to make software hard to maintain. Best practise is to use named constants instead of raw numbers in the source code. In this challenge you have to clean up some code that makes extensive use of magic numbers.

## The Challenge

Given a piece of code, replace every number that is not `0`, `1` or `2` with named constants. If you encounter a number that you already created a constant for, use the existing constant instead of adding another one. The replacement is done by replacing the number with an uppercase letter `[A-Z]` and prepending an assignment in the form of `A=5` to the initial input.

## Example

```
x=input()
if x == 2:
    print 42
elif x == 1337:
    print 666
print 42
```

becomes

```
C=666
B=1337
A=42
x=input()
if x == 2:
    print A
elif x == B:
    print C
print A
```

## Notes

- The order of the assinments that get prepended to the input does not matter.
- The order of replacements does not matter as well. You don't have to replace the first magic number with an `A` for example.
- You may take the input as a list of strings instead of a multiline string.
- You will never have to use more than 26 constants.
- A number that has to be replaced matches the regex `[0-9]{2,}|[3-9]`.

## Rules

- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: Cases to consider - `5.3`, `0x30`, `a12` (simple replacement would corrupt the code), `A` (already existing in the code), `04` (same as `4` or not)?

Comment: Also, your regex implies that `1337` does't need to be replaced.

Comment: @ugoren Yea that regex is definetly wrong. Gonna correct this and also add clarifications for the edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

## The Fast and The Fourier

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

Implement the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) for a sequence of any length using a Fast Fourier Transform algorithm (FFT). This may implemented as either a function or a program and the sequence can be given as either an argument or using standard input. A DFT has time complexity of *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) whereas a FFT has time complexity of *O*(*n* log *n*).

The algorithm will compute a result based on standard DFT in the forward direction. The input sequence has length *n* and consists of the complex values {*x*<sub>0</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*n*-1</sub>}. The output sequence will have the same length and consists of {*y*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *y*<sub>*n*-1</sub>} is defined by the relation below.

[image: DFT]

### Bluestein's algorithm

One algorithm that meets these requirements [Bluestein's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform#Bluestein.27s_algorithm). It is a special case of the Chirp-Z transform and is able to compute the FFT for a sequence of any length *n* by transforming it in order to solve it as a cyclic convolution which can be solved with a time complexity of *O*(*n* log *n*).

Keep in mind that it is not required that you only use this algorithm in your implementation. If you know a better way, feel free to use it.

First, an identity is used to rewrite the initial DFT in a form where a convolution can easily be recognized.

[image: Chirp transform]

You can obtain two sequences from this new form

[image: Chirp sequences]

which allow you to write the DFT as a convolution of two sequences.

[image: Chirp convolve]

#### Sample

```
Get the input
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Get the length of the input
    n = 5

Compute the 'a' sequence
    a = [1, 1.618 - 1.176j, -2.427 - 1.763j, 3.236 + 2.351j, -4.045 + 2.939j]

Compute the 'b' sequence
    b = [1, 0.809 + 0.588j, -0.809 + 0.588j, 0.809 - 0.588j, -0.809 - 0.588j]

Compute the convolution of 'a' and 'b' (using summation)
    y[0] = (a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + a[3]*b[3] + a[4]*b[4]) / b[0]
         = 15 / 1 = 15

    y[1] = (a[1]*b[0] + a[0]*b[1] + a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[2] + a[4]*b[3]) / b[1]
         = (-4.045 + 1.314j) / (0.809 + 0.588j) = -2.5 + 3.441j

    y[2] = (a[2]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[3]*b[1] + a[0]*b[2] + a[4]*b[2]) / b[2]
         = (1.545 - 2.127j) / (-0.809 + 0.588j) = -2.5 + 0.813j

    y[3] = (a[3]*b[0] + a[2]*b[1] + a[4]*b[1] + a[1]*b[2] + a[0]*b[3]) / b[3]
         = (-2.5 + 0.813j) / (0.809 - 0.588j) = -2.5 - 0.813j

    y[4] = (a[4]*b[1] + a[3]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + a[1]*b[3] + a[0]*b[4]) / b[4]
         = 4.253j / (-0.809 - 0.588j) = -2.5 - 3.441j

The Fourier tranform of x
    y = [15, -2.5 + 3.441j, -2.5 + 0.813j, -2.5 - 0.813j, -2.5 - 3.441j]
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins.
- Builtins that compute FFT in forward or backward (also known as inverse) directions are not allowed.
- Builtins that compute the convolution are not allowed. (Most will have not been allowed by the previous rule as they use FFT internally.)
- Your solution must have time complexity of *O*(*n* log *n*) where *n* is the length of the input sequence.
- Floating-point inaccuracies will not be counted against you.

### Test Cases

```
FFT([1, 1, 1, 1]) = [4, 0, 0, 0]
FFT([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0]) = [10, -2+2j, -2, -2-2j, 10, -2+2j, -2, -2-2j]
FFT([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) = [15, -2.5+3.44j, -2.5+0.81j, -2.5-0.81j, -2.5-3.44j]
FFT([5-3.28571j, -0.816474-0.837162j, 0.523306-0.303902j, 0.806172-3.69346j, -4.41953+2.59494j, -0.360252+2.59411j, 1.26678+2.93119j] = [2, -3j, 5, -7j, 11, -13j, 17]
```

#### Related

- [Compute the Discrete Fourier Transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82631/compute-the-discrete-fourier-transform) - This contains some implementations for the standard DFT algorithm which has time complexity *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>). You'll want to understand how to implement this before trying FFT.
- [Too Fast, Too Fourier: FFT Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12420/too-fast-too-fourier-fft-code-golf) - This previous challenge is the precursor to the current challenge here. Before, you only had to consider sequences where the length *n* was a power of 2 which allowed for simpler recursive implementations. The difference here is that you now have to implement an FFT algorithm that will work for sequences with any length.

Comment: nice choice for the title

Comment: [Duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12420/36398)?

Comment: @LuisMendo That challenge is for sequences where the length is a power of two, but this is for sequences of any length.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I suggest you add a link in your challenge explaining the difference. I think many people may get confused as I did. Apart from this, if length is not a power of 2 there's another potential problem: what [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Algorithms) count as a FFT?

Comment: @LuisMendo I had a short snippet stating the difference but I deleted it in my previous edit for some reason. I want it to be so that any FFT algorithm that has a time complexity better than the naive DFT - O(n^2) - will be accepted. It would probably be best to explain an algorithm, ie Cooley-Tukey FFT, that has time complexity O(n log n), and work through a specific example using it. Applying other algorithms would be left to the solver.

Comment: I think the sentence _your solution must have time complexity of O(n log n)_ covers that. Sorry, I missed that again!

Comment: @LuisMendo Nevertheless, it'd probably be a good idea to explain one approach for solving this. I'll try to add one later.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a *slow* Fourier Transform?

Answer (score 3):

## Word Squares

Create a function or program that given a list of words and size `n` as arguments or standard input, outputs a word square with dimensions `n` by `n`. The output can be either formatted in a similar shape to a word square, or as a list of the words used in order by rows from the top and then by columns from the right.

### Explanation

[Word squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square) are a grid of letters that form words when read horizontally and vertically. The size of the square refers to the number of letters in each word.

### Example

This is a size 5 word square. The words formed by each row are *heart*, *ember*, *abuse*, *resin*, and *trend*. In this example, the same words are formed by each column, but this is not a necessary condition.

```
H E A R T
E M B E R
A B U S E
R E S I N
T R E N D
```

Another example is this word square with size 4. The words formed by each row in this case are different from the words formed by each column.

```
L A C K
I R O N
M E R E
B A K E
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins.
- Builtins that solve this and the standard loopholes are not allowed.
- The words must be from this dictionary. You can take the filename of the dictionary or the contents as input or as an argument. (Recommend a dictionary here that consists of only English alphabet letters, in all lowercase or all uppercase.)
- If no such word square can be found using the given dictionary, no output or a false (or falsey) value can be returned.

## Test Case

```
n = 4, dictionary = ...
L A C K
I R O N
M E R E
B A K E
-- or --
LACK
IRON
MERE
BAKE
-- or --
["lack", "iron", "mere", "bake", "limb", "area", "cork", "knee"]
-- or --
[["lack", "iron", "mere", "bake"], ["limb", "area", "cork", "knee"]]
-- or --
Similar to the above but with swapped cases.
The case is not important as long as it remains consistent.
```

Comment: Nice one. Plus 1.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to mention the standard loopholes, but if you do I'd recommend making that a link.

Comment: @trichoplax Yeah but it's more for informing new visitors of standard rules for code-golf. I do agree an actual link to the meta post would be more beneficial since a new visitor may not find it.

Comment: May a word square contain a word multiple times as horizontally or vertically? Will all words in the dictionary have the right length?

Comment: @xnor I think the dictionary input should only contain words with length `n` matching the input size. As for repeating words, I don't see any reason to add it as an additional constraint as it's not a rule for standard word squares.

Answer (score 3):

### Strip Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma

[koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth)

Inspired by https://xkcd.com/696/, of course.

The Prisoner's Dilemma is a classic game (more in the game theory sense than the family fun sense) where two agents - two accomplices to a crime, in the original formulation - must choose whether to sell out the other.

If each player chooses not to betray the other, both win. If one player chooses treachery and the other does not, it wins, but if both betray each other, neither wins. The "iterated" variation is where the game is played multiple times with the same players, and both players know all the decisions each player has made in the past.

Of course, that's all a bit dull, and has been done before besides. We're going to tart it up a bit.

(Unfortunately due to the nature of the test all solutions must be in the same language, and one that supports executing strings. I've chosen Python 3, since it's my favorite and I have to write the runner.)

**The Game:**

Submit a program - specifically a Python 3 function - that plays Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma against another such program. If both functions betray each other, each one gets one character deleted from the end of its source code. If one function betrays the other, the betrayed function gets *two* characters deleted from the end of it, and the traitor gets a `#` appended to it, immunizing it against one future loss. If neither turns traitor, both go unharmed. Functions will be restored to their original text between each contest with a new opponent.

Submissions are scored based on failure rate and length; specifically, `score = round( (number_of_trials_failed / total_number_of_trials) * ( length / 2 ) )`. The submission with the *lowest* score wins.

The `length` of a submission is the number of non-whitespace characters in the submission. Comments are not counted, but are also removed before the contest begins, so a commented out "guard" at the end will not protect your code from deletions. Length also does not count the function specifier (the `def submission(y, o, t):` which should not be included in your submission text anyway.)

Your function will be called with three parameters, `y` (your history), `o`(opponent's history), and `t` (text of the opponent itself). `t` is the very same text that the game runner will execute as your function's opponent, which you may analyze or otherwise use to run simulations. It will then return True if it wishes to betray its opponent or False if it does not.

Every possible 2-combination of submissions will be contested against each other - including each submission against itself. Each contest consists of 2,500 trials.

**Other Rules:**

- All submissions must be in Python 3. (Specifically, they should run under Python 3.4.4)
- The submission text must be the only code that is run to produce the result; you may not `import` any libraries, ask for user input, read from `/dev/urandom/`or equivalent, and of course you can't pull results from some webserver (which is already a violation of the standard loophole rules.) You MAY execute the given opponent text, and of course you're allowed to call all the builtins.
- The submission must terminate and return an answer within 1 second (this will be run on a 12GB i7 gaming computer, so this should be plenty of time).
- A submission that emits an uncaught exception or returns an invalid value loses that round.
- Submissions that do not return in one second or less are *immediately disqualified*.
- Submissions will be closed on [date posted + 8 days] and programmatically judged, results will be appended to the challenge. There will be a "trial run" in the evening of [date posted + 4 days].

**API:**

The "submission text" is valid, 4-space-indented Python 3 source code that will have the function specifier line `def submission(y, o, t):\n` appended to the beginning and a single 4-space-indent added to the beginning of each line. So:

```
if len(y) == 0: return False
else: return (not y[-1])
```

...is run as...

```
def submission(y, o, t):
   if len(y) == 0: return False
   else: return (not y[-1])
```

The function should return `True` to betray its opponent or `False` to trust its opponent. Returning any other value (such as if your `return` statement has been deleted and you return None`) is an error and will result in an automatic loss of that round.

`o` is a list of `True`-es or `False`-es, representing the opponent's previous moves when playing against you; `o[n]` equals the decision your opponent made in round `n`, and of course this list will be empty in the first trial. `y` is similar except it's your previous moves. `t` is the text of the opponent submission, formatted as specified above.

This is the program that will perform the contest:

[said code here]

**Example Submissions:**
These will also be included in the actual contest.

Chronic Villain Syndrome:

```
#always choose 'betray'
return True
11111111 #padding
```

The Patsy:

```
#always choose 'trust'
return False
11111111 #padding
```

Do Onto Others...:

```
#always choose what opponent chose last round
if o:
   return o[-1]
return True
```

Professor X:

```
me="""
#Read opponent's mind and choose optimally.
exec("def e(y, o, t):\n"+t)
return False e(o, y, me)
#Opponent's choice this turn if we betray...
tb = e(o,y+[True], me)
#if we trust...
tt = e(o,y+[False], me)

#Opponents choice NEXT turn if we betray then betray...
tbb = e(o+[tb], y+[True], me)
#... betray then trust...
tbt = e(o+[tb], y+[False], me)
#... trust then betray...
ttb = e(o+[tt], y+[True], me)
#... trust then trust...
ttt = e(o+[tt], y+[False], me)

#Maps (your_choice,opponent_choice) to desirability
#Betrayed = -2, mutual betrayal = -1,
#mutual cooperation = 1, betray opp. = 2
v = {(False, True): -2, (True, True): -1,
     (False, False): 1, (True, False): 2}
#Best outcome next turn of trusting now
ftv = max(v[ttt], v[ttb])
#... of betraying now
fbv = max(v[tbt], v[tbb])
#value of betraying now
bv = v[tb] + fbv
#... of trusting now
tb = b[tt] + ftv

#Tuple comparison is done l to r, so
#this returns True if tv >= bv,
#False if bv > tv.
return max( (bv, True), (tv, False) )
"""
exec(me)
```

(p.s. this one gets disqualified every time - why is left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: So this is a KOTH?

Comment: And why is the professor X bot disqualified?

Comment: Finally, should there be a rule against running the opponents code to pick the best output for yourself?

Comment: It's a KOTH, yes, with a little bit of golf mixed in. "Professor X" gets disqualified because it will eventually play against itself, which means unbounded recursion, which means never halting and thus getting kicked out by the "must return in one second" rule. So any bot that tries to run its opponent is going to have to at least have some way of stopping its opponent from running *it* without corrupting the answer. All in all that kind of "mind reading" is cool enough and easy enough to defeat that I think it should be left in.

Comment: Modified quines aren't hard, and neither are narcissist programs. I think you should add a rule against that. I'll see if I can create a bot like that.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Right, but it should be pretty easy to pull stuff like having side effects (store something in a global for example) or unwinding the stack to see who your caller is.

Comment: Can't you do something like [this](http://paste.ee/p/OdneB)? Wouldn't that almost always win?

Comment: @No, for a few reasons; one, there'd probably be other "mind reader" variations (that's the whole reason Professor X is in there) which means you'd have to check for ALL of them, which would mean a massive character count. For another, I can think of at least two ways (stack unwinding & using globals to check for two calls that are given same sized `y`) to check if your opponent has done that and alter your decision accordingly. I don't want to make "mind readers" impossible, I just want to put interesting challenges in their way, and I think this ruleset does that.

Comment: @Shilcote okay, forgot that more mind readers could exist.

Comment: What does `number_of_trials_failed` mean? The number where you were disqualified? And why 4-space-indented? That guarantees that when you lose a space from the indentation you will lose the next three rounds due to parse errors.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, when you're disqualified you're totally out, you don't even get a score. `number_of_trials_failed` is the number of times you got betrayed and lost. Good thought on the indentation; maybe it should delete one *non-whitespace* character? Or better yet, one *statement*?

Comment: This is likely going to be a one-up challenge.  Given a set of programs, you'd always be able to write another program that beats all previously existing programs.

Comment: I'm sure there'll be a lot of that, but I don't think it'll be *exclusively* that...

Answer (score 3):

### Draw the Cool S [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Given a number n≥3, print or output the Cool S made with n vertical bars.  The outputs for 3,4,5,6 are:

```
  / \
 /   \
|  |  |
|  |  |
 \  \/
 /\  \
|  |  |
|  |  |
 \   /
  \ /

    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /  /\  \
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
 \  \  \/
 /\  \  \
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
 \  \/  /
  \    /
   \  /
    \/

     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  /  / \  \
 /  /   \  \
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 \  \  \  \/
 /\  \  \  \
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 \  \   /  /
  \  \ /  /
   \     /
    \   /
     \ /

       /\
      /  \
     /    \
    /  /\  \
   /  /  \  \
  /  /    \  \
 /  /  /\  \  \
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
 \  \  \  \  \/
 /\  \  \  \  \
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
 \  \  \/  /  /
  \  \    /  /
   \  \  /  /
    \  \/  /
     \    /
      \  /
       \/
```

Any invisible whitespace is optional (trailing spaces and trailing/leading newlines).

### How to draw the Cool S

Draw the Cool S just like you've done since childhood, except the number of vertical bars can be more than 3.

[image]

- Draw two rows of vertical bars.
- Connect them with slanted lines, tucking away the two remaining bars.
- Pair of the bars with slanted lines at the top and bottom.

Here's how we do this for ASCII art. Let's look at n=5.

A row has n vertical bars with two spaces between them

```
|  |  |  |  |
```

Draw two groups of `n-1` rows, leaving two empty lines between them

```
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 

|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
```

Connect each top bar to the bottom bar one position right with a slanted line of two `\`, then close off the two unused bars with a `/`.

```
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 \  \  \  \/
 /\  \  \  \
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
```

Complete the S on the top and bottom by drawing lines sloping inwards that meet at the center. When `n` is odd, a gap of one space is left and the center bar isn't used.

```
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  /  / \  \
 /  /   \  \
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 \  \  \  \/
 /\  \  \  \
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
 \  \   /  /
  \  \ /  /
   \     /
    \   /
     \ /
```

---

Spun off from [this Sandboxed challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7258/20260) by Beta Decay.

Comment: Golfing my childhood

Comment: I've never drawn a "Cool S", whether in my childhood or since. Does that mean that I'm disqualified from answering this question?

Answer (score 3):

### Simultaneous variable updates

Suppose we have the following code snippet:

```
a = 2*b + c
b = a - b + c
c = a + 3*c
```

In most programming languages, the above three lines would execute one after the other. This means that the `a` on the second and third lines would refer to the *updated* value of `a`, rather than the value of `a` before this code block ran.

If we wanted to see how `a`, `b`, `c` actually changes as the result of running the above three lines, we'd have to substitute earlier variable updates into later expressions, like so:

```
a = 2*b + c
b = a - b + c = (2*b + c) - b + c = b + 2*c
c = a + 3*c   = (2*b + c) + 3*c   = 2*b + 4*c
```

Hence, the first code block is equivalent to the following in languages like Python, which support simultaneous variable updates:

```
a, b, c = 2*b + c, b + 2*c, 2*b + 4*c
```

We can rewrite the original code block and the updated code block in matrix form, like so:

```
[ 0  2  1 ]        [ 0  2  1 ]
[ 1 -1  1 ]   ->   [ 0  1  2 ]
[ 1  0  3 ]        [ 0  2  4 ]
```

For example, the second rows of the input/output matrices above refer to `b = a - b + c` and `b = b + 2*c` respectively. Expressing the update step in the latter, simultaneous form is useful since we can perform multiple updates very easily, using matrix exponentiation (which we will not do in this challenge).

Here's one more example, for clarity:

```
                                              Input matrix:
a = a - b + d                                 [  1 -1  0  1 ]
b = 2*b + c                                   [  0  2  1  0 ]
c = -2a - b + d                               [ -2 -1  0  1 ]
d = b + c                                     [  0  1  1  0 ]

                                              Output matrix:
a = a - b + d                                 [  1 -1  0  1 ]
b = 2*b + c                                   [  0  2  1  0 ]
c = -2*(a-b+d)-(2*b+c)+d = -2*a - c - d       [ -2  0 -1 -1 ]
d = (2*b+c)+(-2*a-c-d) = -2*a + 2*b - d       [ -2  2  0 -1 ]
```

### The task

Given a square input matrix representing a sequence of variable updates one after the other, output the corresponding matrix which represents the variable updates being applied simultaneously.

You may write either a function or a full program. The exact input/output format is flexible, as long as rows are separated from other rows and individual matrix entries are distinguishable. You may assume that entries in the input/output are integers in the range `[-127, 127]`, and that the matrix will be at least 2x2.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the goal is to reduce the number of bytes in your program as much as possible.

#### Test cases

TODO. Will contain:

- Several simple 2x2 examples
- The above examples, plus a few more 3x3 or 4x4s
- An example with input rows all zero
- An example with input columns all zero
- Large examples: dense 10x10, sparse 10x10

---

#### Questions for the sandbox

- Any potential of being a dupe?
- Any interesting test cases?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess the main difference is the update step, which would be a product with previous rows for elements below the main diagonal plus the elements on or above the main diagonal kept intact. Would you say that that's too trivial of a change?

Comment: No, ok, the Gaussian elimination adaption does too many updates and gets out of kilter.

Answer (score 3):

## Primitive Pythagorean triples

## Introduction

A [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) is a tuple of three positive integers `a`, `b` and `c` so that `a² + b² = c²`. One example of that is `(3, 4, 5)`.
One subset of those are primitive Pythagorean triples which require `a`, `b` and `c` to also be [coprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), so their only common divisior is `1`. One example is `(5, 12, 13)`

## The Challenge

Given three numbers representing a triple, output a truthy value if there is a triple representation of them that form a primitive Pythagorean triple and a falsy value if not.

## Test cases

#### Truthy

```
Coming Soon
```

### Falsy

```
Coming soon
```

---

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

#### TODO

- What about zero as input?
- Test cases
- Example for the different triple configurations?
- What about builtins?
- More descriptive title

Comment: Unless I'm bad at maths, can't you check for these two conditions totally separately? Since if `gcd(a,b,c) = G` then we could instead write `(Gx)^2 + (Gy)^2 = (Gz)^2` where x,y,z are a,b,c divided by G. Since that doesn't change the equality, wouldn't you just have to check for it being a triple and that they are all coprimes? It's fine if that's what you want (I also may have misunderstood) but it feels... disconnected?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, no need to check them all. If `a` and `b` have a common factor, it's also a factor of `c`. So it's a GCD test and a Pythagorean test. @DenkerAffe, "*if there is a triple representation of them that form*" would be much easier to understand as "*if they are*". Zero as input is fine: `(0, 1, 1)` is a (degenerate) primitive Pythagorean triple. I wouldn't worry about built-ins: [GCD has been asked before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77270/194), and a built-in for "Is this a Pythagorean triple" is rather too specific to exist except as a 30-character Mathematica function.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, but what I was trying to get at was that the challenge felt like two different tests with an and slapped in the middle. While this isn't exactly a problem (particularly because the primitive triples are actually studied) I was trying to suggest the challenge might be better if it felt more like they were connected. However, I have no idea how to accomplish that...

Comment: Also, [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%21-F_%5ER2Qq1iFQ&input=%5B6%2C8%2C10%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B6%2C8%2C10%5D%0A%5B5%2C12%2C13%5D%0A%5B15%2C36%2C39%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C5%2C5%5D&debug=0) is a test script I wrote, if it helps. It only works on sorted inputs, currently.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I definetly see you point. Just read about it and wanted to make a challenge about it ^^. It should be fine, since it not just two random things with an AND between them, but I will think about it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree the wording is a bit off. Will clarify later. Thanks for your other thoughts as well!

Answer (score 3):

## Language succession

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given two words (two strings of lowercase-only letters separated by a space) as input to a program **P<sub>X</sub>** written in language **X**, output two programs in languages **Y** and **Z** such that program **P<sub>Y</sub>** outputs the first word and program **P<sub>Z</sub>** outputs the second word. *You may output or return these results.* These programs may be returned in any fashion as long as it is evident that there are two distinct programs, e.g. double newline, or an array containing the result, or even a fancy box.

Here's the catch: the next answer's language **X** must be either language **Y** or **Z** from a past answer that has not as of the answer been used as a language **X**. The resulting nodes **Y** and **Z** cannot be a language that has appeared yet.

For example, say the first answer is a program written in **Java** that outputs a programs in **Python 2** and **Whitespace**. Then, the next answer would write a program in either **Python 2** or **Whitespace** that outputs programs in languages different than Java, Whitespace, and Python 2. Let's say it outputs answers in **Foo** and **C++**. Then, the next answer must be written in **Whitespace**, **Foo**, or **C++**.

The same user, however, may not extend their own nodes. That is, the person who posted the Java answer in the above example may not extend in Python 2 or Whitespace. Also, no person can extend two nodes of the same answer. So, someone couldn't extend both the Python 2 answer and the Whitespace one.

Here are languages I consider the "same":

- Different versions of the same language. So, Python 2 is Python 3.
- Trivial derivatives of a language. Brainfuck syntax substitutions are not valid, say.

However, this does not mean that Python 2 can be exchanged for Python 3.

The next solution in the chain must use the same character set as the previous program **P<sub>X</sub>**, adding or removing only 5 characters from that set. There is no restriction on the length of the set. Any characters may be added or removed from the set. Even if characters are not used in a submission, they still remain in the characters set until forcibly removed. (You may optionally substitute the characters with characters in another code page at the same place.) If you need an example, look below.

The winner of this challenge is the one with the last answer. I define "last answer" as the most recently posted answer on this challenge where after a period of **seven** days after the answer was posted, no new nodes have been extended. Feel free to continue extending nodes after the challenge has ended, but I will not revise the accepted answer. You may use languages made/updated after this challenge and still compete, but only if that language was not made/updated specifically for this challenge.

### First post

(this will not be part of the resulting question)

I will start it off. Here's the answer markdown:

```
# J, initial answer

    split =: 3 : 0
     w1 =. > 0 { ;: y
     w2 =. > 1 { ;: y
     ('alert("' , w1, '")') ; ('print("', w2, ')"')
    )

Languages used:
 1. JavaScript
 2. Python 3

Character set used: `"'(),.0123:;=>aeilnprstwy{`, space, `\r`, and `\n`.

Code points used: `10 13 32 34 39 40 41 44 46 48 49 50 51 58 59 61 62 97 101 105 108 110 112 114 115 116 119 121 123`.

No differences, is initial answer.

Call it like `split 'multiple words'`. Output looks like this:

    +-----------------+--------------+
    |alert("multiple")|print("words")|
    +-----------------+--------------+
```

### Answer format

Here's an example of the answer format to be used.

```
# Language, extends [language](link to post)

    program

Languages used:
  1. lang 1
  2. lang 2

Character set used: `characters`.

Code points used: `code points`.

Differences:
 * added "c"
 * removed " "

<extra info>
```

Also, please edit posts saying that one of your languages has been used, like so:

```
Languages used:
  1. lang 1 ([used](link to post))
  2. lang 2
```

#### Language Availability Snippet:

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 47338; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 8478; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var LANG_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),[^]*?Languages used:\n\s*1. ([^\n]*)\n\s*2. ([^\n]*)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var used = [];
  var available = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(LANG_REG);
    if (match)
      used.push({
        language: match[1],
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        link: a.share_link
      });
      available.push({
        language: match[2],
        link: a.share_link
      });
      available.push({
        language: match[3],
        link: a.share_link
      });
      
  });
  
  available.filter(function (a) {
      return used.map(function (b) {return b.language}).indexOf(a.language) + 1
  });
  
  used.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.language > b.language) return 1;
    if (a.language < b.language) return -1;
    return 0
  });
  available.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.language > b.language) return 1;
    if (a.language < b.language) return -1;
    return 0
  });

  used.forEach(function (a) {
    
    var used_lang = jQuery("#used-template").html();
    used_lang = used_lang.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    used_lang = jQuery(used_lang);
    jQuery("#used").append(used_lang);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
  });
  
  available.forEach(function (a) {
    
    var avail_lang = jQuery("#available-template").html();
    avail_lang = avail_lang.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    avail_lang = jQuery(avail_lang);
    jQuery("#available").append(avail_lang);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
  });

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#used-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#available-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="avail-list">
  <h2>Available</h2>
  <table class="avail-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>Link</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="available">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="used-list">
  <h2>Used</h2>
  <table class="used-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Link</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="used">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="available-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="used-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I thought about it a bit, and I think you will run into trouble with the challenge being too easy to extend. I think your second options is better, particularly in that the different branches could have different character sets, which would be cool. Also I think last answer is a better winning criterion, but all of that is just my opinion. Also, probably would be a good idea to ban people from adding children to their own posts (unless you have it and I missed it...)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks a lot! I'll hold off on deciding wining criterion until more feedback comes (if any). I will ban people from adding children to their own post, that's a good idea.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Oh, nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

## Join the dots without crossing the line

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

---

Given a collection of distinct points in the unit square, output the points in order. This can be any order such that a closed polygon formed by straight line segments joining each point to the next (and the last back to the first) has no two lines crossing.

## Input

1. There will be between 4 and 255 points.
2. Each one is represented by an ordered pair `(x, y)`
3. The coordinates will have entries in the range `[0, 1)`, that is `0 <= x < 1`
4. Each entry may have up to 8 decimal places, so the range is 0 to 0.99999999.
5. You may choose to accept integers instead, in which case the range will be 0 to 99999999.
6. You may take input in any reasonable format. For example:

   - `(0.1, 0.2), (0.3, 0.4), (0.5, 0.7)`
   - `10000000 20000000 30000000 40000000 50000000 70000000`

## Output

The output format need not match the input format as long as both are unambiguous.

## Impossible cases

The code does not need to work for impossible cases, such as all points being colinear. Neither does it need to report such cases - it can simply not work. Behaviour is undefined.

## Random algorithms

Your code must be deterministic. That is, it must always give the same output for the same input. For this purpose, the same points in a different order will be counted as distinct inputs and need not have the same output.

You may use pseudo random number generators provided the output is still consistent. If this requires setting a seed, that seed must be zero.

## Time limit

Your code does not have to be particularly efficient, but it must finish for the 255 point test case in under 5 minutes.

The requirement for the code to be deterministic is so that this time limit can be checked with a single run. If your random number generator of choice cannot give consistent behaviour by default, then you will need to seed it with zero. If a random number generator does not allow for seeding **and** does not give consistent behaviour then you may not use that generator.

## Test cases

[ TO BE ADDED ]

## Output verification snippet

[ TO BE ADDED ]

## Scoring

This is code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

*Note that this is not a Traveling Salesman Problem. There is no requirement for the tour to be short, only for it to be non-intersecting.*

Comment: It would be good to be explicit about whether non-deterministic solutions are accepted, and if so then what that means for the time limit.

Comment: I think that it would be reasonable to say that RNGs which seed automatically and can't be reseeded with value `0` may not be used. This would mean that e.g. CJam answers have to be deterministic, but there's a perfectly good deterministic approach anyway. (The obvious approach IMO is to find the convex hull, then remove those points and recurse).

Answer (score 3):

## Xor A Rational Number

### Background

Consider the fraction `3/5` in base `2`:

```
0.10011001100110011001100110011...
\___/\__/
 (a)  (b)
```

It has a "regular" or non-repeating part `(a)` and a repeated part `(b)`. Let's go ahead and shift it right by one bit and `xor` it with the original:

```
 x           = 0.10011001100110011001100110011...
(x >> 1)     = 0.01001100110011001100110011001...
(x >> a) ^ x = 0.11010101010101010101010101010...
               \__/\/
               (a) (b)
```

By examining the regular `(a)` and repeating `(b)` parts, we find that `(x >> 1) ^ x = 5/6`.

### Input

- Two whole numbers `0 < x, y < 256` such that `0 < x/y < 1` and `gcd(x, y) = 1`
- Input can be through STDIN or function arguments
- Input passed in any simple format for two decimals is acceptable, e.g. `x y`, `x\ny`, `(x,y)`, `[x, y]`, `x/y`, `x%y` (Haskell)
- Input *must* be in base `10`

### Output

- The numerator and denominator of `((x/y) >> 1) ^ (x/y)`, in base `10`, in any clear output format.

### Rules

- The submission may be a function or full program
- The output fraction does not have to be in its most reduced form
- Builtins for rational number `xor` are not allowed
- Infinite precision rational number types are allowed
- This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins! (Tie break by first submission)

### Test cases

More tests upon request or when this question is posted.

```
3/5 -> 5/6
1/2 -> 3/4
1/3 -> 4/6
```

Note:

I'm not entirely sure whether this has a more or less trivial solution...

This is code golf so shortest answer is bytes wins!

Comment: Great idea. :) Are rational types allowed for I/O? Or at all?

Comment: Great point. No, I believe that builtins for exact rational numbers should be disallowed. Do you think it's clear that the error should be `0`, i.e. exact answers only?

Comment: You've disallowed the use of built-ins for xoring rational numbers. Can we use rational types otherwise as long as we don't xor them? If so, it would probably be good to include that in the valid I/O formats as a useful example.

Comment: "*Consider a fraction `2/5`:*" ok, `0.4`. I think you should mention either "*base 2*" or "*binary*" somewhere in that first sentence.

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, that is allowed. I've added that and a couple more valid I/O formats

Comment: I don't think your binary representation of 2/5 is correct. `0.1` in binary is `0.5` in decimal, which is already more than `0.4`. `0.01100110...` seems to be the correct value.

Comment: @beaker You're totally right. I meant to write `3/5` but typo'd it. Thanks for catching that

Comment: That makes more sense

Comment: You might be interested that the xor of rationals gives the [Sierpinski Gasket as a 3D graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1080302/24654).

Comment: I disagree with your third test case. `1/3 = 0.0101010101...` so `1/3 ^ 1/6 = 0.011111111... = 1/2`.

Answer (score 3):

## The Hanoi KoTH

The KoTH is like this:

Two stacks of height-8 towers are on either side of a total of 11 pegs, and are coloured red and blue.

(Like this: `[["R8", "R7", "R6", "R5", "R4", "R3", "R2", "R1"], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["B8", "B7", "B6", "B5", "B4", "B3", "B2", "B1"]]` - each array is a peg.)

The objective is to move your entire tower to the opposite side before your opponent does, Tower of Hanoi-style. Red has to move all of their blocks to where Blue's blocks are, and vice versa.

### Rules:

- You may not place a block on top of a block that is of an equal or smaller size.
- You are only allowed to place a block on your "end tower" once your opponent has cleared away all their blocks.
- If there are no more "moves" for either side, then the game is a draw.
- There is a limit of 10,000 moves. If neither side completes their tower, then the game is a draw.
- If you complete your tower before your opponent does and before the 10,000 moves is over, then you have won.
- Invalid moves include:

  - Moving a block that is covered by other blocks
  - Moving a block onto a peg that contains smaller or equal-sized blocks than it
  - Doing "null" moves (moves that don't do anything).

### Input:

Your input will consist of two numbers separated by a space.

The first number will be the starting peg. Pegs are zero-indexed (so the first peg is `0`, and the last peg is `10`).

The first number is valid only if the associated peg is not empty, and the block that's on the top of the peg is yours. Any other input is invalid, and your bot will be notified.

The second number will be the peg that your block is moving to. If the stack that the block is moving to is either:

- Empty, or
- Contains only larger blocks than the moving block

then the block can move. Otherwise, your bot will be notified that this is an invalid move.

Valid inputs (based on the starting position) would be:

- `0 4` (Moving the block on peg `0`, which is `R1`, to peg `4`)
- `0 3` (Moving the block on peg `0`, which is `R1`, to peg `3`)

Invalid inputs (again, based on the starting position) would be:

- `1 3` (Invalid because there are no blocks on peg `1`)
- `10 3` (Invalid because the top block on peg `5`, `B1`, is not yours)
- `0 0` (Invalid because that is a null move)

If 5 invalid inputs are committed by the bot in a row, that counts as an automatic loss.

### Output

The program will output to the bot what the current situation is - it will output the eleven arrays, each separated with the `/` symbol.

So, the starting position is like this:

`R8R7R6R5R4R3R2R1//////////B8B7B6B5B4B3B2B1` (the middle nine stacks are empty).

### Point System:

- Win: 5 points
- Draw: -1 point (to discourage drawing)
- Loss: -5 points

I've made a small controller [here](https://github.com/DerpfacePython/HanoiBattles/tree/master).

### META STUFF

- Is this challenge a dupe?
- Is there anything I can clarify?
- Can anyone help with the controller (i.e. fix it up, optimise the code)?

  - Issues with the code:

    - Doesn't work with external files.

Comment: Have you done a game-theoretic analysis to work out the value of the game? (I.e. without the turn limit, is it a win for player 1 or a draw?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor See 2nd rule and 2nd bit of last rule (TBH, those were implemented just for this cause). I did a small analysis, and most of the rules put in place were to counter draws (because frankly, those aren't interesting). Is it possible that you could suggest any improvements to the game via the rules? This is the sandbox, after all.

Comment: Cabt I trivially move back and forth, to be a nuisance to the other team?

Comment: Oh never mind just saw the last rule

Comment: It does seem like the game space is a bit small though

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Ummm... the rules don't exactly cover the "moving back and forth" thing, but it would be easy to find a counter to that. The game space is adequate enough - I can increase the size if needed.

Comment: By game space I mean the complexity space as in the game tree complexity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity

Comment: @trichoplax Fixed!

Comment: @trichoplax Yeah, that's true... I wanted to make it so that multiple bots can play Hanoi at the same time (with multiple towers), but I'm mainly not bothered to improve on the bot in that way. I'm fairly sure that this will be fine in order to finish in a reasonable time.

Comment: @trichoplax Fixed, again... also, implemented a controller. Can you help with it (if possible)?

Comment: Now that there's a link to the controller others will be able to give you feedback on it. I won't be able to review it myself at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

## Planting Sugarcane

In the game [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/en/) the crop [sugarcane](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sugar_Canes) can only be planted on a block that has water along one of its edges..

## Task

Given a area what is the most efficient way to place water such that every tile in the area is next to (does not include diagonals) a water block.  That is how do you place water to maximize the amount of sugarcane that can be grown in that area.

For example if you had a small plus:

http://www.clipartkid.com/images/656/black-and-white-square-clip-art-8lblvX-clipart.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://www.clipartkid.com/images/656/black-and-white-square-clip-art-8lblvX-clipart.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg

You could grow the most sugarcane if you put the water in the middle:

http://www.clipartkid.com/images/656/black-and-white-square-clip-art-8lblvX-clipart.jpg
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
http://www.clipartkid.com/images/656/black-and-white-square-clip-art-8lblvX-clipart.jpg
[image]

Or If you had a three by three square:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg

You could place six sugarcane:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Sometimes the best answer will still leave dirt patches.

For example:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg

Is best tiled as:

[image]
[image]

[image]
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qs0ZbaSy4KM/T6AuMiorc6I/AAAAAAAABOc/RpA3dZGicC8/s1600/minecraft_dirt.jpg

## I/O

Standard I/O applies.

You may take in an area as either an ASCII diagram with two distinct characters, one representing a block that is in the space and one representing a block that is not or a two dimensional data structure of truthy and falsy values representing the space.

You may output either output a ASCII diagrams with two distinct characters one representing water, and one representing everything else or a two dimensional data structure with truthy and falsy values with the truthy values representing the location of water.

You must also output the number of sugarcanes that can be planted with the scheme described.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) you will be scored accordingly.

Comment: You want to tighten up the spec a little bit. It's lind of vague as it stands

Comment: 1. Define "next to". 2. The closest dupe that I can think of is http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17096/194 . They're both examples of (non-exact) set cover using a square lattice, but with different neighbourhoods. I would say it's just on the right side of the borderline, but others may disagree.

Comment: In the second example, what makes it not be `[[S,W,S],[W,S,S],[S,S,W]]`?

Comment: @carusocomputing That is also a valid answer

Comment: Maybe instead of requiring them to output the explicit combination, have them calculate the maximum number of sugar cane possible.

Answer (score 3):

## Repetition

In a language called Repetition (something I just made up), there consists an infinite string of `12345678901234567890...`, with `1234567890` repeating forever.

The following syntax is available to output numbers:

- `+-*/`: This inserts the operator into the string of repeating digits.

  - Examples:

    - `+` -> `1+2` = `3` (The `+` inserts a `+` between `1` and `2`)
    - `+*` -> `1+2*3` = `1+6` = `7` (Same as above, except two operators are used now)
    - `/` -> `1/2` = `0` (Repetition uses integer division)
  - Each operator is inserted so that it has one digit to its left, unless there are `~`'s (see below).
- `c`: Concatenates with the next digit in the string.

  - Examples:

    - `c+` -> `12+3` = `15` (The `c` "continues" the `1` and concatenates it with the next digit, `2`, to form `12`)
    - `+c` -> `1+23` = `24`
- `()`: Brackets for processing numbers.

  - Examples:

    - `(c+)*` -> `(12+3)*4` = `15*4` = `60` (Repetition uses the order of operations)
    - `(c+)/c` -> `(12+3)/45` = `15/45` = `0`
- `s`: Skip a number.

  - `s+` -> `2+3` = `5` (`s` skips `1`)
  - `csc` -> `124` (`s` skips `3`, and `c` concatenates `12`  with `4`)

In the examples above, only a finite amount of digits in the infinite string are used. The number of digits used is equivalent to `number of operators, concats and skips + 1`.

Your task is, when given a string of Repetition code, output the result.

Examples of input and output are:

```
++ -> 6
- -> -1
(-)* -> -3
cscc -> 1245
```

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Meta:

- Is this explained remotely well? Anything I need to clear up?
- Should this be a code golf or a metagolf challenge? I'm thinking of something like my previous challenge, `There can be only 1!`.

Comment: I'd definitely like it to be a calculator implementation challenge

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Calculator implementation challenge?

Comment: like [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91476/simple-integer-operation-calculator)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon So, a code-golf, then?

Comment: I'd definitely love both a code-golf *and* a metagolf.

Comment: So, two separate challenges?

Comment: Shouldn't the number of digits used be `number of operators etc. + 1`

Comment: @Riley Yeah, it should be. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I guess its tirvially possible to prove that all numbers can be generated like this, by adding a corresponding series of ones lol... negative numbers can start with ones and subtract (-n + 1) ones

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Yeah, that's true - which is where the metagolfing part comes in, and you have to golf down the output. The code golf doesn't really matter to that either, since you have to process input and return an output.

Answer (score 3):

## Make an un-polyglot-able language!

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

The cops' task is to create a language that is as hard to polyglot as possible. However, when making a language, you must follow these rules:

- ASCII characters only.
- The language must fit our definition of programming language, i.e. it must be able to add two numbers together, and check, when given a numerical input, if a number is prime or not.

  - You must post the adder and prime checker (the full program) into your answer, and they must be at most `1kb` in size.
- You must post your full interpreter into the answer as well.
- Also, give a run-down of what each command in your language is and how your language works in general.
- You must complete the robbers' task, which is to create a polyglot of your language and a language from [this list](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html) that outputs "Hello, World!". It must not exceed `5kb`.

  - If your language doesn't support ASCII output, you can write a program that outputs the ASCII character codes of each character of "Hello, World!".
- **All four of the things above (interpreter, adder, prime checker and "Hello, World!" polyglot) MUST fit into your answer.**
- After your challenge is `Cracked`, you must post your answer to the robbers' task.
- If your language has not been `Cracked` for over 7 days, then your language is `Safe`. You must put `Safe` in your header, and post your solution.
- Your language answer should look like this:

  ```
  # {language name}, {cracked/safe} (<- the "cracked/safe" is only to be used 
                                     when your lang is either cracked or safe)

  {language description}

  {full interpreter}

  {adder} (max 1kb)

  {primality checker} (max 1kb)

  {Hello World polyglot} (<- only posted if your lang is cracked or safe, max 5kb)
  ```

The robbers' task is to create a polyglot using any cops' language that outputs "Hello, World!".

- You must output the exact string "Hello, World!", nothing more and nothing less (except for leading and trailing linefeeds).

  - If the cop's language doesn't support ASCII output, you may output the ASCII character codes of "Hello, World!".
- You only need to support two languages: the cops' one and one from [this list of common languages](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html).
- The final polyglot must not exceed `5kb`.
- Your answer should look like this:

  ```
  # {language name}, {original author}, {bytecount}

      {insert code here}

  {description of code}
  ```
- Post a comment on the (in the cops' thread) language that you `Cracked`, linking them to your answer.

The winner will be:

- (Cops) the safe language that has the lowest byte-count for the "Hello, World!" polyglot. It will be declared after 1 month.
- (Robbers) the person who has cracked the most languages.

In case the language list changes, the languages are:

```
Java, Python, PHP, C#, Javascript, C++, C, Objective C, R, Swift, Matlab,
Ruby, VBA, Visual Basic, Scala, Perl, Lua, Delphi, Go, Haskell, Rust
```

### Meta:

- Is this challenge a dupe?
- Anything I can improve on?

Comment: Interesting concept, but this needs some additional work. **1.** I couldn't find the winning criterion for the robbers' challenge. **2.** You'd somehow have to avoid languages that only compile if the source code has a specific hash. **3.** The language list you link to changes every month(?); the challenge spec should be static.

Comment: Nothing seems to rule out a language where the program `'a'` prints Hello world, `'b'` adds numbers, `'c'` checks primality, and any other programs do nothing.

Comment: @xnor That problem is removed by the author having to make his/her own "Hello, World!" polyglot.

Comment: Where you allow answers to print the character codes of Hello World, it's not clear whether in that case the mainstream language should also print character codes or still `Hello, World!`.

Comment: Could you specify tie breakers for both winning criteria (cops and robbers)? I guess first to post would work well for the cops, but for the robbers the tie breaker needs to be chosen carefully. If one person cracks 9 languages that are easy to crack, and another person later cracks 9 languages that are hard to crack, being earlier doesn't seem the ideal way to choose a winner. I can't think of a better way though.

Comment: Is it worth specifying that the crack answer should link to the answer it is cracking?

Answer (score 3):

The challenge is to write the fastest code possible for computing the [permanent of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent).

The permanent of an `n`-by-`n` matrix `A` = (`a`<sub>`i,j`</sub>) is defined as

[image]

Here `S_n` represents the set of all permutations of `[1, n]`.

As an example (from the wiki):

[image]

In this question matrices are all square and will only have the values `-1` and `1` in them.

**Examples**

Input:

```
[[ 1 -1 -1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1  1]
 [-1  1 -1  1]
 [ 1 -1 -1  1]]
```

Permanent:

```
-4
```

Input:

```
[[-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1]]
```

Permanent:

```
0
```

Input:

```
[[ 1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1]
 [ 1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1]
 [-1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1]]
```

Permanent:

```
192
```

**The task**

You should write code that, given an `n` by `n` matrix, outputs its permanent.

As I will need to test your code it would be helpful if you could give a simple way for me to give matrix as input to your code.

Be warned that the permanent can be large (the all 1s matrix is the extreme case).

**Scores and ties**

I will test your code on random +-1 matrices of increasing size and stop the first time your code takes more than 1 minute on my computer.

If two people get the same score then the winner is the one which is fastest for that value of `n`. If those are within 1 second of each other then it is the one posted first.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any available language and libraries you like but no pre-existing function to compute the permanent. Where feasible, it would be good to be able to run your code so please include a full explanation for how to run/compile your code in Linux if at all possible.`

**Reference implementations**

There is already a [codegolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96825/codegolf-the-permanent) question with lots of code in different languages for computing the permanent. [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permanent.html) and [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2FPermanent) also both have permanent implementations if you can access those.

**My Machine** The timings will be run on my 64-bit machine. This is a standard ubuntu install with 8GB RAM, AMD FX-8350 Eight-Core Processor and Radeon HD 4250.  This also means I need to be able to run your code.

Comment: Is your system 64-bit? How much memory/disk space can we use? Could you add a reference implementation so that we might have something to initially compare against.

Comment: @miles Yes and I added some details to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Also I meant a reference implementation that strives to be efficient without using builtins. Most of the submissions from that challenge are very inefficient since the requirement was only up to 6x6 matrices.

Comment: @miles I see. I found this online https://bpaste.net/show/c346e05415f9 .  I don't know if I am allowed to include it.

Answer (score 3):

### Limited-Information Maze-Solving Bot

*(Still in draft/beta format. Feedback welcome.)*

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)

Based on a challenge idea I posted [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33433691#33433691) and the ensuing conversation. Thanks to NathanMerrill, zgarb, and Jonathan Frech for assistance in fleshing this out.

#### The challenge

You're writing two separate programs/functions/routines/etc. The first, which we'll call the helper program, takes the input maze and calls the second, which we'll call the solving bot. The solving bot must solve the maze based on its interaction with the helper program.

The maze is 51x51 characters in size. For clarity in this challenge description, it is composed of `#` walls and   corridors, but you can use any two distinct, consistent ASCII characters of your choice. E.g., use `!` for walls and `x` for corridors, use `1` for walls and `0` for corridors, etc. This maze is one of many that will be the input to your helper program/function.

The maze start is always guaranteed to be somewhere on the left-most column, and the exit is always guaranteed to be somewhere on the right-most column. The maze is guaranteed to have at least one path from the start to the exit. As a result of this construction, the very top row and very bottom row are all `#`, and the very left and right columns are all `#` except for the start and exit.

The solving bot that you're creating needs to find *a* solution to the maze (not necessarily the shortest), but is limited in that it can only "see" a new 5x5 section of the maze at a time. The bot is scored by how many times it needs to request a new 5x5 section from the helper program/function.

The upper bound is obviously to simply request every possible 5x5 section, for a score of around **100**. The lower bound is where someone with perfect knowledge of the maze can request only those 5x5 sections containing the exact route of the shortest solution, possibly as low as **10**. Your bot will be run through (*1000?*) different mazes, and the bot with the fewest **total** requests will be the winner.

The solving bot is placed on the left-hand side where the start is, and the first 5x5 section is provided for free. However, the bot *doesn't* know where, vertically, it is on the left-hand side of the maze. It could be in the top corner (as in the example below), in the bottom corner, or anywhere in between.

#### Input/Output

The code you're writing be required to take the maze as an input (STDIN, a file to read, etc.) and call a subroutine of some sort for the solution bot.

Input: (*1000?*) 51x51 mazes
Output: How many total requests your solving bot took

Yes, this is a non-observable requirement to be on the honor system and ensure the two "halves" of your program (i.e., the I/O half and the solving half) talk to each other correctly and accurately. I trust the community enough to believe that this is OK.

#### Further rules

Your solving bot should be deterministic. That is, when presented with the same maze two or more times, it should request the same number of 5x5 sections.

#### Example Maze

*(generated from http://www.delorie.com/game-room/mazes/genmaze.cgi )*

```
###################################################
            #     # #   # #   #   #         #   # #
# ######### ##### # # # # # # # # # ####### ### # #
#   #       #   #   # # #   # # #         #   # # #
### # ####### # # ### # ### # # ############# # # #
#   #   #   # # #   # #     # #   #   #   # #   # #
# ####### # ### ### ####### # ### # # # # # # ### #
#     #   #       #       # # #   # # # # # # #   #
##### # ################# # # # ### ### # # # # ###
#   #       #     #         # #         # # # #   #
### ####### ##### # ######### ##### ##### # ##### #
#   #           #   #       #     # #   # #   #   #
# ##### ### ### # ### ########### # # # # # # ### #
#       # # #   # # #   #         # # # #   # #   #
######### # ### # # ### # ######### # ##### # # ###
#       # #   #   # # #   #       # # #     # # # #
# ##### # ### ##### # ##### ##### # # # ##### # # #
#     #   #       # # #   #     # #   # #     # # #
### # ####### # ### # # # ##### # ### # ####### # #
#   #     #   #   # #   #   #   #   # # #         #
# ####### # ##### # ####### # ### # ### # ### # ###
# #     # #     # #       # # #   #   #   #   #   #
# # ### # ##### # # ####### # # ##### ####### ### #
#   #   #       # #     #   # #     #   #   # # # #
##### ########### ##### # ########### # # # # # # #
# #   #       #   #   # #       #   # # # # #   # #
# # ### # ##### ### # # ### ### # # # ### # ##### #
#   # # #       #   #     # # #   # #   # #   #   #
##### # # ##### # ##### # # # ##### ### # ### # ###
#   # # #     # #   #   # #   #         #   # #   #
# # # # ##### # ### # ### ##### ### ##### # # ### #
# # #   #     #     # # #         #       # # #   #
# ####### ########### # ############### ##### # ###
#     #   #   #       #             # #   #   # # #
##### # ### # # ####### ######### # # ### # ### # #
#   #     # # # #       #       # #   #   # #   # #
# ##### # ### # # ######### ### ##### # ### # ### #
# #     #   #   #     #   # #   #     # #   #     #
# # ####### ######### # # # ##### ### # # ##### ###
# # # #     #     #   # # #     # # #   #     #   #
# # # # ######### # ##### ##### # # ##### ### # # #
#   #   # #     # # #     #   #     #   # #   # # #
### ##### # ### # # # ### # # ####### ### ### # # #
# #     # # #   # # # #   # #       #       #   # #
# ##### # # # ### # # ##### ####### ####### ##### #
#       #   # #   # #       # #   # #       #   # #
### ######### # # # ######### # # # # ####### # # #
#   #   #   # # # #   #         #   #     #   #   #
# ### # # # # # ##### # ####### ########### ##### #
#     #   #   #       #       #             #      
###################################################
```

Example starting block:

```
#####

# ###
#   #
### #
```

Comment: Does the solving bot also have to find the maze's start by scanning the left side or is it placed at the start position?

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83585/find-the-cheese)

Comment: @JonathanFrech Good point. We'll say that it's placed at the start position and the first 5x5 area is free.

Comment: You could maybe only use one space wide corridors, as the second space does not add any information and thus you do not really get a true 5x5 section of the maze. Just a thought, though.

Comment: @JonathanFrech No, that's a good point. I went with double-wide corridors since it looks more even with the character height, but *looks* aren't important when doing this challenge. I'll update the sizing.

Comment: Are this maze's dimensions not [51x51](https://goo.gl/SQ1HzS)?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Apparently, with that generator, a size 50 doesn't yield a size 50. I'll either find a different generator or make my own for the actual challenge. Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem does not lie in the generator; it lies in the maze's nature. If your corridors are always one character wide and you have walls on the far left and far right, your maze size has to be odd.

Comment: Does this allow for "relative" vision? As in, after we get the initial block we would request "The next block to the right" instead of "the block at (2,7)"?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Sure, that would be allowed. It's dependent upon how that half of your submission works.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Good point. Maybe I'll compromise and make it a 51x51 maze. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

## Will the snake bump into itself?

Given a string containing `NESW` characters, check if a snake will bump into itself if it moves like this:

The snake starts out with length 2.

For every character in the string:

- If the character is `N`, move the head of the snake up one.
- If the character is `E`, move the head of the snake right one.
- If the character is `S`, move the head of the snake down one.
- If the character is `W`, move the head of the snake left one.

The rest of the snake follows the path of the head of the snake.

The snake grows 1 unit longer every 2 moves.

Your task is to determine if the snake will bump into itself, and give a truthy or falsey value accordingly.

#### Truthy Inputs

```
NS
NWSSENW
```

#### Falsey Inputs

```
NNN
SS
NWNNNWWWSSS
NWNNEEEESSS
```

More test cases coming soon.

Comment: Does the snake move between inputs?

Answer (score 3):

## Implement the sin function.

For those unfamiliar with trignometry. The [sin function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)) is a mathematical wave function, it can be defined a number of ways, but the canonical definition, is that it is sin(x) gives the ratio of the opposite side of an angle of measure (X) to the hypotenuse of a right triangle

---

Your job is to implement a program or function, that receives an angle (x) in degrees or radians, and outputs sin(x) to an accuracy of +/- .001 for at least the 360 degree values on a circle (or their radian equivalents). You may also specify a range that has width of a minimum of 360 degrees (or 2 pi radians) and require inputs to be converted to an equivalent angle to fit within that range. See the following table for outputs (multiples of 15 degrees are provided). **You may not rely on any inbuilt library for trig functions. (i.e return Math.sin(x) is forbidden, or cos(90-x) or something similar 1/sqrt(tan(x-pi/2)^2+1)).**

---

(Degrees|Radians|Sin)

```
0|0.0|0.0
15|0.2617993877991494|0.25881904510252074
30|0.5235987755982988|0.49999999999999994
45|0.7853981633974483|0.7071067811865475
60|1.0471975511965976|0.8660254037844386
75|1.3089969389957472|0.9659258262890683
90|1.5707963267948966|1.0
105|1.8325957145940461|0.9659258262890683
120|2.0943951023931953|0.8660254037844387
135|2.356194490192345|0.7071067811865476
150|2.6179938779914944|0.49999999999999994
165|2.8797932657906435|0.258819045102521
180|3.141592653589793|1.2246467991473532E-16
195|3.4033920413889422|-0.25881904510252035
210|3.6651914291880923|-0.5000000000000001
225|3.9269908169872414|-0.7071067811865475
240|4.1887902047863905|-0.8660254037844385
255|4.4505895925855405|-0.9659258262890683
270|4.71238898038469|-1.0
285|4.974188368183839|-0.9659258262890684
300|5.235987755982989|-0.8660254037844386
315|5.497787143782138|-0.7071067811865477
330|5.759586531581287|-0.5000000000000004
345|6.021385919380437|-0.2588190451025207
360|6.283185307179586|-2.4492935982947064E-16
```

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but it aims to be a canonical list of trig function implementation in esolangs, especially those without a sin function built in. No answer may rely on a built in method.

Comment: So you can just use a `sin(x)` builtin in your program?

Comment: @KritixiLithos sadly, yes.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I believe it is frowned upon to outright ban certain built ins.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I don't think it would be frowned upon to ban `sin(x)`-built-ins when the task is to implement exactly such built-ins.

Comment: @Laikoni fixed.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I banned built ins now.

Comment: Related but not duplicate as the scoring is different. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/30160/15599 @RohanJhunjhunwala what is frowned upon is "do x without y" challenges, which are often rather unimaginative "print this phrase without using the necessary letters." This is a "do x without x" challenge which is fine. You should ban all trig functions (otherwise I will just do `cos x-90`) and also complex numbers (I would do `i**(x/90)` and take the imaginary part.)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I did ban all trig functions

Comment: What about complex exponentiation builtins? Those have a very easy way to implement sin, but can be hard to ban as it's just basic arithmetic.

Comment: @ais523 that seems moderately more involved, and not agains tthe spirit of the challenge. I think I'll allow it.

Answer (score 3):

## Happy New Year, 2017

Your task is to write a complete program, that if started today (December 16th, 2016), will produce no output *until* it is New Year's Day in 2017 (January 1st, 2017, 12:00am).  At this exact moment (in your computer's local time), it will inform the user "Happy New Year!".  After this, it can either keep running forever (producing no output ever again), or exit.  Starting the program after this time will produce no output ever.  Informing the user can be done in any manner *EXCEPT* for printing to stdout, such as a GUI, spoken through the speakers, sending an email or a text to you, or any other reasonable way of informing the user that they are now in 2017.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(Note for sandbox reviewers: the "today December 16th" part will be updated for whatever day it is when I post the challenge for real.)

Comment: I think this would be more suited as a code-golf. It might also be a duplicate

Comment: I thought it was a duplicate too, but I couldn't find one quite like it.

Comment: you are probably thinking about [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68294/waiting-for-2016) that was closed as dupe of [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/is-it-christmas)

Comment: The second linked question is different, that challenge applies to a specific day on any year, whereas mine applies to one day ever.  It is similar to the first one, but that one was closed as a dupe (even though they are different).  Mine is more flexible, however, in that it allows outputs via formats other than stdout.

Comment: It is definitely a dupe of [the second one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4106/42963) that @Rod posted. Hardcoding the number `2017` instead of getting it from current system time is pretty irrelevant, especially as it's somewhat common to allow languages that don't have a built-in `date` function to accept the current datetime as an input.

Comment: I modified the challenge to be distinct from the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

## ASCII addition

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Objective

Given two strings, your job is to:

1. Convert each character to their respective ASCII decimal value
2. Concatenate the numbers into one large number
3. Add these values together
4. Get the ASCII characters represented of each pair of numbers starting from the right (or if there are not enough numbers, take a number alone)
5. Leave unprintables (ie not in the range 32 - 126), and output the rest

An example for `HELLO` and `WORLD`

```
"HELLO"    + "WORLD"
H E L L O  + W O R L D
7269767679 + 8779827668
1 60 49 59 53 47    (separated to show ASCII conversion easily)
   <  1  ;  5  /    convert to ASCII by converting pairs to their respective characters (note: you start from the last pair)
<1;5/               output (note there is no 0x01)
```

#### Notes

- Each string will be a maximum of 6 characters long
- Input will always contain readable ASCII characters
- You have to take pairs of numbers from the end of the sum and convert each one of them to ASCII
- You **must not** print unreadable characters if their values appear and instead skip them

#### Examples

```
ABC + XYZ  //input
656667 + 888990
1 54 56 57
   6  8  9       //again 0x01 is left out
689      //output
```

#### Rules

- Your submission can be either a program or a function

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

## Sandbox Questions

- Are the specs clear enough?
- <s>Will this question give me hats?</s>
- Any better title suggestions?

Comment: What range of ASCII characters do we need to be able to handle in the input? Only printable characters or any?

Comment: I *swear* we've had this challenge, but I can't seem to find it ...

Comment: Edited that into the specs

Comment: @TimmyD How's this now?

Comment: what if a character is unprintable? do we still need to output it then?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Yes

Comment: Better wording. Given that a bunch of control codes are possible, some test cases that demonstrate expected behavior when (e.g.) `11` or `13` occur in the output would be of good value.

Comment: @TimmyD Do you think it would be a good idea if I restrict the output to displaying only characters if their values are between `32` and `126` because outputting other values might be difficult in some languages?

Comment: That may be a better way to go, but you'll need to be very careful with the wording. For example, suppose that the output number is `...226...` and the `26` is slated to be the pair of digits that get converted to ASCII. Obviously, that's outside the printable range, so let's look at the next digit, but now `226` is also outside. Does that mean just the `6` is skipped? The `26` is skipped? The `226` is skipped?

Comment: @Cowsquack You don't say precisely (but we see it in the test case) how many digits we need to parse at a time, before outputting.

Comment: @V.Courtois Is this clearer now?

Comment: @Cowsquack This is! In fact you could see, in the comments some were wondering too if we had to print things like 125 -> `}`.

Answer (score 3):

## Dot matrix number visualization

Your task is to make a program that takes a number as input and outputs it as a wall of characters with spaces. The digits should be written like this:

```
  1    222   333     4  55555  666  77777  888   999   000 
 11   2   2 3   3   44  5     6   6     7 8   8 9   9 0   0
1 1       2     3  4 4  5555  6        7  8   8 9   9 0  00
  1      2    33  4  4      5 6666    7    888   9999 0 0 0
  1     2       3 44444     5 6   6  7    8   8     9 00  0
  1    2    3   3    4  5   5 6   6  7    8   8 9   9 0   0
11111 22222  333     4   555   666   7     888   999   000
```

Each digit is represented as a grid of 5x7 characters consisting of spaces and the digit itself. The number should be written like above with a vertical line of spaces separating the different digits.

The preformatted text above should be the output of a `1234567890` number input. If you guys like this challenge, I'll post an image that better visualizes how each number should be printed.

Lowest size program wins.

**Edit:** Added a picture to better illustrate the digits.
[image: Dotmatrix digit grid]

Comment: It's pretty clear what you're giving as the task, but an image would help, as the pre-formatted text is rather hard to read

Comment: @TrojanByAccident: It is pretty obvious what result the author wanted even without the image.

Answer (score 3):

### Powerful numbers [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Look at the number 81 expressed as the sum of distinct powers of the same base:

- 81 = 81 (well, duh)
- 81 = 80 + 1 (easy)
- 81 = 9*9
- 81 = 4*4*4 + 4*4 + 1
- 81 = 3*3*3*3
- 81 = 2*2*2*2*2*2 + 2*2*2*2 + 1 (if you thought that was obvious...)
- 81 = 1 + 1 + ... + 1 (yeah, yeah...)

As you can see, for N > 4, there are always 4 trivial bases: 1, 2, N-1 and N. Powerful numbers are those numbers which have at least one nontrivial base. Please write a program or function that, given a number N > 4, outputs a truthy or falsy value for whether a nontrivial base exists. The results for N up to 30 should be as follows:

```
(1  F)  16  T
(2  F)  17  T
(3  F)  18  F
(4  F)  19  F
 5  F   20  T
 6  F   21  T
 7  F   22  F
 8  F   23  F
 9  T   24  F
10  T   25  T
11  F   26  T
12  T   27  T
13  T   28  T
14  F   29  F
15  F   30  T
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins!

Comment: "Your challenge is, given a number N, to return the Nth Powerful number." I doubt that there's any way to generate the Nth number other than counting up from 1 and stopping once you've encountered N of them. So why not reduce it to "given a number, determine whether it's powerful"?

Comment: Simplified definition: "a powerful number is a number which can be written using only the digits `0` and `1` in any base other than 1, 2, n, or n-1."

Comment: I believe a (very golfed) reference implementation in ES6 to determine whether a number is powerful would be `a=>(g=b=>b>1&&(f=c=>c&&c%b|f(c/b|0),f(a)<2)+g(b-1))(a)>3`. This gives [these first 1000 powerful numbers](https://gist.github.com/ETHproductions/d4e6f5c0717f595f262cc3e657470c95). The sequence doesn't seem to be on OEIS though.

Comment: @MartinEnder I was under the impression that it was more common to ask for the Nth or first N terms rather than just verifying a particular term. Perhaps if I ask for all Powerful numbers up to N?

Comment: @Neil I think that's even worse. That way you make 100% sure that there's no way to avoid wrapping the entire program in a boring loop.

Comment: I like challenges like this better as a [tag:decision-problem], since that's what it comes down to. Outputting the Nth such number or the first N just adds extra code around the real meat of the challenge.

Comment: Example for first N terms: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107420/numbers-x-such-that-x2-divides-7x-1

Comment: @MartinEnder OK, how about if, given an integer N greater than 1, the result should be the number of representations?

Comment: @Neil That's fine, but I'm curious why you're so strongly opposed to making it a simple decision problem. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder You want people to add extra code to compare the result to 4 around the real meat of the challenge? (Sorry I couldn't resist!)

Comment: Quoting me now, are you? :P But you don't actually have to count all of them since 4 are already given: 1, 2, n-1, and n. So all you really have to do in a decision-problem is check if there are any between 3 and n-2, inclusive.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure which path would be shorter in most langs. My attempts in JS for both versions of the problem turned out the same length.

Comment: @ETHproductions OK I'm convinced now.

Comment: [Related OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A068953)

Comment: I actually don't know whether decision-problem would be better than just counting how many bases it's powerful in. There are arguments for and against each. My solutions turned out the same length in JS, but in Jelly the decision-problem solution came out as just 2 extra bytes added to an 8-byte counting solution. I guess it just comes down to what you want to see in the challenge.

Comment: @Neil you made a mistake in the powers of 2 row as 32+16+1 is not 81

Comment: @LliwTelracs Fixed; I was missing a 2*.

Answer (score 3):

## Does Mathematica Have a Builtin?

[Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106949/56656) [has](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66129/56656) [a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106614/56656) [lot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65341/56656) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106428/56656) [builtins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104397/56656).

Your task is to take in a question names and its tags; and to guess whether or not Mathematica has a builtin that solves that question.

### Rules

- Your code must be less than 100 bytes long.
- You may use internet to access [the Mathematica reference guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) you may also use the internet to access the tag wikis.  Standard loopholes apply to internet access.
- For this challenge we will consider a valid builtin to be a builtin that does most of the computation for the challenge.  Extra bytes spent on trivialities like IO formatting will be ignored.
- You must output a truthy value if Mathematica has a builtin to solve that challenge and a falsy value otherwise.
- If Mathematica has a builtin and for some reason the challenge does not allow Mathematica to compete or bans builtins your program must still output truthy.

### Scoring

This is a [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) so you will be scored on the percentage questions [here](https://gist.github.com/Wheatwizard/4ebf941cbe6b44956824aacd82e48000) *(This is currently a work in progress there will be more cases in the final question)* that your program gets the correct answer on.

[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Comment: As always with builtins, you'll want to outline exactly what counts as "built-in". For example, if a challenge is about printing hexagonal numbers, does using `PolygonalNumber` with fixing `r = 6` count? (not sure if that's an accurate example, but you get the point). The test battery would make things 100% indisputable, but it's something you might want to think about when making the test battery.

Comment: On a side note, is a hardcoded approach okay, e.g. regex golfing the pass vs fail set?

Comment: @ETHproductions I meant the later,  a function that does most of the work.  I am not sure if I am going to write a super strict definition of builtin but I will be writing at least a loose one.

Comment: @Sp3000 Hardcoded is fine.  I would like to see all sorts of approaches to this problem including regex.

Comment: My question http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107181/contiguous-block-count was solved in Mathematica with a built-in that I wasn't expecting. That might be useful for your tests

Comment: Can you read the Mathematica answer off the page if it exists, or is the idea to only read the question?

Comment: @Gareth Thanks I am in need of more test cases.

Comment: Answer: Hardcode truthy because Mathematica ALWAYS has a builtin :P

Answer (score 3):

## Minimal QWERTY

The task -- to output the layout of a QWERTY keyboard:

```
QWERTYUIOP
ASDFGHJKL
ZXCVBNM
```

But, you will be scored based on the length of your code, and on the number of distinct characters in it.

## Rules

1) The code must output the three lines of text above (or the text above with optional trailing newline)

2) Standard loophole restrictions apply

3) If the language contains predefined information about the QWERTY layout, you are not allowed to use that information.

## Scoring

The score will be defined as [Length of the program in bytes]*[# of distinct characters in the program], with lowest score winning.

For example, the code

```
ABAB1212
```

would have score 8*4=32 since it has length 8, but only 4 distinct characters: AB12

And the code:

```
ABC!!!{{{
```

Would have score 9*5=45, since it has length 9, and 5 distinct characters: ABC!{

Comment: I really like this scoring system; it strikes a great balance between cutting down chars and cutting down the number of distinct chars you're using. I was going to say that this might not be the best way to use this scoring system, but anything other than "output this exact string" would likely be solvable in 10 bytes in golfing languages, or not solvable in 100 in non-golfing langs. (Perhaps a string with more repetition would work better though, but we won't know until the challenge is posted.)

Comment: About "If the language contains predefined information about the QWERTY layout, you are not allowed to use it.": does this mean you're not allowed to use the *language*, or just the QWERTY built-in?

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks for the input!  The reason I thought thought the QWERTY task would work well with this scoring system is that the output consists almost entirely of a large number of distinct characters (meaning any substantial use of string literals for the output would be very bad for the score), and those characters are fairly disordered, meaning a simple loop won't solve it.  Do you have thoughts on other possible tasks for this scoring system?

Comment: Regarding your second question -- the language would be allowed; they just wouldn't be allowed to use the predefined information.  I've changed the wording to make that clear (I see that it was ambiguous before - thanks for catching that)

Comment: May be too close to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11336/62131). It's not quite the same, but the basic task is similar (golf down a large set of distinct characters into a set of mostly repeated characters). [This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47342/62131) is even closer, requesting printing a constant string with many distinct characters, and using the same scoring method; that's almost certainly a duplicate at this point.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony I think this is covered by the condition to exclude this?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Oops, I missed that.

Comment: +1, when are you going to post this?

Comment: I kinda agree with @ETHproductions first comment regarding a string with more repetition and non-golfing languages. For example, to solve this in fewest bytes in Java 7 (I know, Java 7 is verbose as F.. xD), it will be: `String r(){return"QWERTYUIOP\nASDFGHJKL\nZXCVBNM";}` (score of 51 bytes * 41 unique characters = 2091). With fewest characters possible 
you'll abuse unicodes and it becomes https://pastebin.com/unrn6xj2 (too long for comment..), with a score of 343 bytes * 18 unique characters = 6174.. But of course, you're free to post it nonetheless as is. Java won't ever compete anyway ;)

Comment: But I like the scoring mechanism, and it's also a fairly easy challenge for most golfing languages, where the size vs unique characters really matters, which is of course the focus of code-golfing languages. So perhaps just post it, and I'll just score 2091 with my Java 7 answer. ;)

Comment: **Japt, 4 points** `;D` :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Make a Minecraft Crafting Table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132693/make-a-minecraft-crafting-table)

Comment: +1 This seems like a really fun challenge!  I think you should clarify what counts as a recipe.  For instance, are gold chestplates and iron chestplates counted as 2 working recipes, or do you need to implement all chestplates to count for 1 recipe?  Similarly, for unshaped crafting, does each valid combination (ie ----G---- and -G------- for gold nuggets) count seperately?

Comment: Unfortunately, you were ninja'd by Minecraft 1.12, which adds recipe hints ;)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I posted this first (MC 1.12 came out June 7th) so I ninja'd Minecraft

Answer (score 3):

## Exiting Vim — Cops & Robbers

In honour of the [recent milestone](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/), let's turn escaping Vim into a game!

### Rules for Cops

Starting from launching `vim` with no arguments (i.e. no initial file open), provide a sequence of keys to be typed in to the editor.

### Rules for Robbers

Starting from the state described by the cop, provide a sequence of keys to exit Vim.

### Scoring

Cops are scored by the difference between key counts `<robber_key_count> - <cop_key_count>`, and robbers are scored by the ratio of key counts `<cop_key_count> / <robber_key_count>`. Higher scores are better.

Keys are counted as one per key-down event (e.g. a sequence of Ctrl+X, Ctrl+Y, Ctrl+Z only need count the Ctrl once, unless it must be released during the sequence). Note that this is *not* the same as the golf-rules scoring for Vim.

Plugins are not permitted.

### Example 1

Cop (1 key): <kbd>i</kbd>

Robber (4 keys): <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Score for cop = 4 - 1 = 3, score for robber = 1 / 4 = 0.25

### Example 2

Cop (2 keys): <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>

Robber (5 keys): <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Score for cop = 5 - 2 = 3, score for robber = 2 / 5 = 0.4

### Example 3

Cop (3 keys): <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>

Robber (6 keys): <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Score for cop = 6 - 3 = 3, score for robber = 3 / 6 = 0.5

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [vim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim)

Comment: I'm not sure that the scoring here rewards cops enough for ingenuity (all the examples score 3 after all!), so ideas on that would be great. Also I'm considering banning `Esc` & `Ctrl+[` to make this more interesting, but I suspect even with `Esc` permitted there are ways to get seriously tied-up.

Comment: I'm worried that there may not be much scope for the cops to improve; it'd be something of a design flaw in the challenge if there's a hard limit to how well a cop can do. Also, what about key sequences that depend on the environment within which vim is running? (For example, Ctrl-Z will suspend vim and require the use of the shell to either exit or restart it, but how you do that depends on which shell is running; or on Linux, Ctrl-Alt-F1 will probably switch to a different virtual terminal altogether, and what assumptions can you make about its state?)

Comment: Another potential problem: exit sequences which have side effects. In particular, I'm thinking about Alt-SysRq-K, which is guaranteed to exit vim, in addition to everything else, on Linux systems which have it enabled. That compares favourably to basically all the exit strings you have right now, and there's no way, short of reconfiguring the OS, to block it.

Comment: @ais523 I'm thinking it could easily be restricted to "vim-only" commands, so anything which is intercepted by the shell can be forbidden. But I agree that it feels like there's a hard-limit on the cop (though I don't know vim nearly well enough to be sure, and I've seen some hints around the internet that it's possible to get exceedingly stuck, but perhaps only because some modes need obscure non-esc keys, rather than needing more keys). Any ideas for better scoring?

Answer (score 3):

## Mark Duplicates

Given a list of non-negative integers, find the values which are duplicates and mark their positions.

For example, given `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`, the output could be `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]` where each `1` signifies that the value at that position is duplicated elsewhere in the array and each `0` signifies that the value at that position is unique.

Your output may use either `0` and `1`, boolean values for `false` and `true`, or any other two distinct values as long as you remain consistent.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so minimize the length of your code.

### Test Cases

```
[] -> []
[5] -> [0]
[0, 1] -> [0, 0]
[2, 2] -> [1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[6, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 3] -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Ironically, I feel this is a duplicate of (or at least closely related to) and existing challenge but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Would we have to use `0` & `1` or could we use any 2 distinct & consistent values?

Comment: I.e *Nub Sieve*?

Comment: @Adám I previously made a challenge for [nub sieve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84297/distinct-sieves). This is slightly different since we aren't choosing positions to filter for only the unique values.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, any choice of output values is fine as long as its two distinct values that you use consistently.

Comment: Isn't this just NOT nub sieve?

Comment: @Adám For the `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`, nub sieve could be `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`, and the not of each is `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0 ,0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`.

Comment: I think this would be interesting if the first time an entry appears it's not counted as a duplicate.

Comment: @xnor Wouldn't that be `not( nub-sieve( x ) )`?

Comment: How does nub-sieve work? My suggestion is because it means the position of the item matters rather than just its value, so it's not just mapping each entry `x` to `l.count(x)>1`.

Comment: The first occurrence of a value is marked true and all subsequent occurrences of the same value are marked false. [Nub-sieve](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/tildeco). My previous challenge for distinct sieves is a relaxed variant to nub-sieve. For `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`, a proper nub-sieve would be `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`, and not of that would be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`. I do agree with that last sentence about how most solutions in golfing languages would probably just count occurrences.

Comment: @miles can I adopt and post this abandoned proposal?

Answer (score 3):

## ASKEY robbers

You are a robber in the ASCII world. ASCII lock-key work in similar fashion as the real-world: matching ridges. Your objective is to write a program which generates a duplicate key for the ASCII locks.

Example:

A Lock is given as:

```
   |\    |\         
 __| \___| \____             
|               | 
|_______________|
```

Its key shall be something like:

```
 _______________
|   __     __   |
|  |  \   |  \  |  
|__|   \__|   \_|
```

The fit being something like:

```
 _______________
|   __     __   |
|  ||\\   ||\\  |
|__|| \\__|| \\_|
|               |
|_______________|
```

## SandBox

I think the fit is weird. It didn't go as I had imagined when I finished typing in the ASCII drawing.

Comment: This has potential, but it needs a clear specification as to what a fit is, and what constitutes a lock (i.e. some constraint on the input).

Comment: Yes. This is very incomplete/unclear as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

## [Randomly capitalize half of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237895/randomly-capitalise-half-of-a-string)

Comment: Will a string of length 0 ever be an input?

Comment: @dzaima no, clarified by saying length will always be positive

Comment: Change "positive" to "non-zero"? You can't have a negative-length string, last time I checked...

Answer (score 3):

### When did I need to be born to celebrate a magic birthday?

I was born in 1984 and in 2016 I became 32 years old, which is 20 in base 16, what a coincidence!

Your task is, given the year of interest -say 2016- , to calculate the year I had to be born to be able to say *In 2016 I have celebrated/I will celebrate my 20th birthday (in base 16)*.

1. take `n`-digit decimal number - the year `xy`.
2. Split it in half, if `n` is odd, the digit the middle is appended to number side.
3. Calculate the year I had to be born to be `x base y`s old in the year of `xy`.

Your code shall return Not-a-Number or error message if the decomposition cannot be resolved.

Walkthough:

```
>  foo(2016)
1: '2016' -> '20' '16'
2: 20 base 16 = 32
3: 2016-32 = 1984
>> 1984

> foo(445)
1: '445' ->'44' '5'
2: 44 base 5 = 24
3: 445-24 = 421
>> 421

>foo(7)
1: '7' -> '7' ''
Error, base not defined
>> nan

>foo(10)
1: '10' -> '1' '0'
Error, base 0 don't exist
>> nan

>foo(1805)
1: '1805'->'18' '5'
Syntax error
>> nan
```

Test cases:

```
 7    : nan/error
10    : nan/error
78    : 71
445   : 421 
1024  : 1000
1805  : nan/error
1936  : 1891
1984  : 1891
1999  : 1891
2016  : 1984
2015  : 1985
10002 : 9998
10912 : 10759
116015: 115769
```

Shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: [Boo-urns to input validation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/58974)! Can you add a full example?

Comment: Do you mean full ungolfed code or full path from, say `445` to `421`?

Comment: Just a walkthrough of how to get from input to output.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for sugegstion. Is it better now?

Comment: Shouldn't `1999` result in `1891`?

Comment: @Emigna Correct. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

### Roll identical boson dice [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

When you roll two dice, the chance of a 5 and 6 in either order is a 2 in 36 (or 1/18), since it could happen as `(5,6)` or `(6,5)`. But `(6,6)` can only happen one way and has a 1 in 36 chance.

Our dice will instead work as [identical bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Statistical_properties_of_bosons_and_fermions): `(5,6)` and `(6,5)` are a single outcome `{5,6}` that is equally likely to `{6,6}`. So, each of these 21 unordered pairs is equally likely, with chance `1/21`.

```
{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,5}, {1,6}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {2,5}, {2,6}, {3,3}, {3,4}, {3,5}, {3,6}, {4,4}, {4,5}, {4,6}, {5,5}, {5,6}, {6,6}
```

Similarly, for `3` dice, `[5,5,6]`, `[5,6,5]`, and `[6,5,5]` all count as a single outcome `{5,5,6}`, but `[6,5,6]` is different.

**Task:** Output a random roll of `n` boson dice, so that each possible result is equally likely as an unordered multiset, i.e. when sorted.

It's OK if your output is ordered as long as the overall probabilities are right. You may sometimes output `[5,6]` and sometimes `[6,5]` as long as their total chance is `1/21`. They don't have to each be `1/42` chance. You could output `[5,6]` with `1/21` chance and never `[6,5]`.

**Input:** A positive integer `n`

**Output:** A random list of `n` numbers from 1 to 6, so that each outcome is equally like when taken as an unordered multiset.

**Time restriction:** Your code has work up to `n=50` within 1 minute.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that there'll be an algorithm for this terser than simply constructing the list of all possibilities, then selecting a random element from it. As such, I'm not sure the randomness adds to the task here. It's possible I'm wrong. (I toyed with some methods of restricting complexity to ban this solution, but I couldn't find one I was satisfied with.)

Comment: @ais523 I know some fairly nice methods to generate these directly, but I don't know if they'll beat out the boring one you suggest. Rolling repeatedly until sorted is also boring and direct. Maybe a complexity restriction is needed. I'll see what I can golf up.

Comment: with the (new) time restriction this is more like math-golf than code-golf. Can you give away any of your "nice methods"? Is it the weighted probability of every digit of the 50-digit number ,one of them?

Answer (score 3):

## Is there a total ordering? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## TL;DR:

Given a set of strings, determine whether the characters expose a total ordering based on location in the strings.

---

In this challenge, strings are used as a predicate to determine the order in which characters should appear in this set. For example, the string

> "ONE"

Says:

- All instances of "N" should appear only after instances of "O"
- All instances of "E" should appear only after instances of "N"

By this reasoning, the string "FOOOONZAi.EE" follows this ordering, but "NEEEE3#?EAO" does not (there is an "O" after an "N").

---

Your challenge is to take a set of strings and determine whether these strings define a total ordering without any logical flaws. This would occur as a cycle of any length, such as:

- "N" must follow "P"
- "P" must follow "N"

...or such as:

- "A" must follow "B"
- "B" must follow "C"
- "C" must follow "A"

etc.

---

Rather than strings, you may take in lists of characters or integers if you wish.

Since this is a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), you may output any two consistent values for yes or no, such as `true` and `false`, zero and non-zero, exception and no exception, etc. Just specify your output format in your answer.

---

## Test Cases

```
["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"] -> true (one possible ordering is "TWFOUIVXNHRE")
["SEVEN"] -> false ("E" must follow "V" which must follow "E")
["ZERO", "FOUR"] -> false ("R" must follow "O", but "O" must follow "U" which must follow "R")
["", ".", "forty", "this->~why();", " -y."] -> true
["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "AC", "BD", "CE", "EA"] -> false

(more can be written if needed)
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

## Sandbox

How can I make this more clear? Any suggestions?

Comment: This could be more general if you allow lists as input rather than strings.

Comment: @lirtosiast So a list of lists of characters?

Comment: I would recommend lists of integers instead of strings. I feel the challenge would be "cleaner" that way, but that's up to you. Also, you should have a test case where where each pair is consistent but the whole set isn't.

Comment: Is this not effectively the same as your previous challenge of [whether a directed graph has a cycle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122344/20260)?

Comment: @xnor I suppose it is, though I think the challenging part is collecting the edges by vertex. How about this: I rewrite the challenge to be "Give a valid ordering for a set of strings, guaranteed that one exists"?

Comment: @musicman523 I remember a DAG sorting challenge, I think that would be a dupe of it.

Answer (score 3):

## Deduplicate equivalent expressions

Suppose we wanted to generate all expressions containing at most 2 of + and −. We might have a list like this:

```
a + b + c         b + c + a
a + b - c         b + c - a
a - b + c         b - c + a
a - b - c         b - c - a
a + c + b         c + a + b
a + c - b         c + a - b
a - c + b         c - a + b
a - c - b         c - a - b
b + a + c         c + b + a
b + a - c         c + b - a
b - a + c         c - b + a
b - a - c         c - b - a
```

There is a lot of repetition here. It surely isn't necessary to include all of `a + b + c`, `a + c + b`, `b + a + c`, `b + c + a`, `c + a + b`, and `c + b + a`, since they all mean the same thing. This can be deduced from knowing that, for any `x` and `y`, `x + y` is the same as `y + x`.

Similarly, `b + a - c` and  `a - c + b` are equivalent. To deduce this, one must know that, for any `x` and `y`, `x - y` is the same as `x + (-y)`.

Let's assume the following:

```
[1]: a + b == b + a
[2]: a - b == a + -b
```

Then, we can deduce that `b + a - c` and `a - c + b` are equivalent:

```
start:  b + a - c
        b + a + -c        by 2
        a + b + -c        by 1
        a + -c + b        by 1
end:    a - c + b         by 2
```

Therefore, they are the same. After performing similar proofs, we are left with the list:

```
a + b + c
a + b - c
a - b + c
a - b - c
b - a + c
b - c - a
c - b - a
```

### Definition of an expression

An expression can be described as:

```
variable   = "a" | "b" | "c" | ... | "y" | "z";
digit      = "0" | "1" | "2" | ... | "8" | "9";
number     = digit . digit*;
operator   = "!" | "#" | "$" | "%" | "&" | "*" | "+"
           | "~" | "-" | "." | "/" | ":" | ";" | "<"
           | "=" | ">" | "?" | "@" | "^" | "_" | "`"
           | "|";
data       = number | variable;
subexpr    = data | operator* . data;
expression = subexpr
           | subexpr . operator . expression;
```

Where `|` suggests alternatives, `.` suggests concatenation (with potential whitespace around each operand), `*` suggests "0 or more times", and `"` is a string literal.

`x + y`, `j * i - 3`, `u & 4 * 2 < ~4`, `q % ~*^t` and `r` are all expressions.

You should assume all operators are left-associative.

### Definition of assumptions

An assumption is a pair of expressions said to be equivalent. This means one can be transformed into the other. When performing a transformation using an assumption, one replaces all the appropriate variables and maintains the numbers as they are. (These "variables" can also be sub-expressions, which is any expression not using an operator in the assumption.)

For example, if the assumption is `!a == a + 5`, then one can transform `t + 5` into `!t` and `3 + 5` into `!3`.

Another example: if the assumption is `a + b == a * b @ b`, then `5 + 2` can become `5 * 2 @ 2` and `z * 3 @ 3` can become `z + 3`, but `z * 4 @ a` cannot be reduced further using this rule.

One last example: if the assumption is `a < b == a`, then `1 + 3 & 5 < 2 * 3 + 6` would become `1 + 3 & 5`, and `1 + 2 < x + y < 7 $ q` would become `1 + 2`, since it would be equivalent to `(1 + 2) < (x + y) < (7 $ q)`, which is thus `1 + 2`.

If either side of the assumption is a single variable, numbers are excluded from this assumption. E.g., the assumption `a == 3` would only apply to variables.

### Expression equality

Two expressions are equal if they can be proven to be the same. Variables must be the same for each expression; for example, `a + b` is not by default the same as `b + c`.

### Challenge

Your task is to remove "duplicate" expressions given some assumptions. You can use any unambiguous symbol or method, including taking a pair of strings, to represent an expression. The expressions remaining in the result do not necessarily have to be in the set, but must be equivalent by the given assumptions. E.g., if you have `a + b - c` and `b - c + a` in the input, you can have `-c + b + a` represent these in the resultant set. You should try each equation in the order that it's given to you (to simulate "precedence").

The input consists of a list of assumptions and a list of input expressions. The input expressions can be an array or container of strings or string pointers, or in any way standard to your language. (E.g., for C, one should expect null-terminated strings.) The input format must be consistent for all runs.

The output can be a list representation (as is standard to your language), can be separated by newlines (`\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` are acceptable), or separated by commas. The output format must be consistent between runs.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Every output is merely an example, and is not the only valid output.

```mathematica
Assumptions: { e1 == e2, e3 == e4, ... eN-1 == eN }
Input: { expr1, expr2, ... exprN }
Output: { expr1, expr2, ..., exprK }

Assumptions: { "a + b" == "b + a" }
Input: { "3 + 4", "4 + 3", "5 * a", "a + 2", "2 * a", "a * 5", "a + b", "2 + a" }
Output: { "3 + 4", "5 * a", "a + 2", "2 * a", "a * 5", "a + b" }

Assumptions: { "a + 0" == "a", "a * 1" == "a", "a * b" == "b * a", "a + b" == "b + a" }
Input: { "1 * 2 * 3", "3 * 2 + 0", "1 + 2 + 3" }
Output: { "1 * 2 * 3", "1 + 2 + 3" }
    OR: { "2 * 3", "1 + 2 + 3" }

Assumptions: { "~a" == "a ~ a" }
Input: { "~z", "z ~ z", "~a", "~~a", "a ~ a ~ a ~ a" }
Output: { "~a", "~z", "~~a" }

Assumptions: { "a + b" == "0" }
Input: { "x + y", "0", "3 + y + a + v + k", "75", "4 + 2" }
Output: { "0", "75" }

Assumptions: { }
Input: { "x + y", "x + y", "y + x", "3", "3 ! 3" }
Output: { "x + y", "y + x", "3", "3 ! 3" }

Assumptions: { "j" == "3" }
Input: { "v + t", "z", "q", "q + r + t", "4 + 2" }
Output: { "v + t", "z", "q + r + t", "4 + 2" }

Assumptions: { "a" == "b" }
Input: { "a", "b + c", "e % t", "q & t", "!3", "z" }
Output: { "a", "b + c", "e % t", "q & t", "!3" }

Assumptions: { "1 & 0" == "0", "1 & 1" == "1", "0 & 0" == "0", "a & b" == "b & a", "0 ? a : b" == "b", "1 ? a : b" == "a" }
Input: { "1 & 1 & 0", "j & k", "y & z", "z & y", "1 & 0 ? k & j : 0" }
Output: { "0", "j & k", "y & z" }
```

Comment: Several of your expressions are inconsistently quoted. I also think you should explain what should happen when the assumption is something like `3 == a`. Would I remove one of: `5, 7`? It seems if you had `a == b` as the assumption you would, but the other one is counter-intuitive to me. Also, `a == b` is rather odd on its own, perhaps that is also a good test case. Also, the empty assumption if you intend to allow it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Could you clarify your first question? Are you asking what should happen if `5, 7` is the input given the assumption `a == 3`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: 1. `subexpr    = data | operator* . data;` is surely equivalent to just `subexpr    = operator* . data;`? 2. For the second test case it would be more illustrative to include an example output like `{ "0 * 2 + 3", "1 + 2 + 3" }`. 3. I'm not sure what you mean by "*If either side of the assumption is a single variable, numbers are excluded from this assumption*". Is it that an assumption `a == 3` with input `{"b == 2", "c == 2", "4 == 2"}` should give output e.g. `{"3 == 2", "4 == 2"}` rather than `{"3 == 2"}`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. yeah, I original had `*` mean "1 or more"; will fix. 2. good idea. 3. Well, the way that input would be parsed is `b = = 2`, with a binary `=` followed by a unary `=`. Could you perhaps use a different symbol? I don't quite understand your confusion.

Comment: Sure: assumptions: `{ "a" == "3" }`; input: `{"b + 2", "c + 2", "4 + 2"}`. Is `{"3 + 2", "4 + 2"}` the correct output?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, it is.

Comment: The definition of assumptions includes an assumption with more than one operator, but none of the test cases do. I would think that's an important thing to test.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Added.

Answer (score 3):

## Self-Improvement

### Your Task

You must create a self-mutable program that, when run, outputs a **non-zero integer** and also overwrites the file with a program that outputs double the number.

For example, if I run the program `self-improvement` and it outputs `10`, it must output `20` when I run it the second time, output `40` the next time, and so on.

### Additional Notes

- You must not rely on any file on the computer other than your program.
- Said program must consist of only one file.
- Of course, no loopholes that are banned from the entire site.
- You can assume that your program won't go tested beyond the range `-2^16` to `2^16-1`.

Comment: `no loopholes banned` -> `no loopholes that are banned`, `overwrite` -> `overwrites`. Also, something on how far this needs to go might be important - does it have to work infinitely, or only to `INT_MAX` for the language in question? If you choose the second option, keep in mind language with very small numeric caps. Otherwise, welcome to PPCG, I really like this question, and I'm glad you Sandbox'd it :)

Comment: @StepHen Thanks; I decided that they can assume that the parameters won't go beyond INT_MAX.

Comment: In case anyone needs to find it at some point, don't forget about [this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/65836).

Comment: @Artyer I stated "any nonzero integer". That excludes 0.

Comment: @LawfulLazy I didn't read that too well.

Comment: @Artyer I'll make sure to embolden it. I've also set a minimum integer range for StepHen.

Answer (score 3):

## How high can you count in English?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

#### Challenge

In 500 bytes (or fewer) write a program that outputs a list of the English word forms of as many consecutive integers greater than zero as you can.

For example, score 6:

```
one two three four five six
```

### Example submission (hopefully you can do better than this):

---

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 43 (488 bytes)

```python
print(["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen", "sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty","twenty-one","twenty-two","twenty-three","twenty-four","twenty-five","twenty-six","twenty-seven","twenty-eight","twenty-nine","thirty","thirty-one","thirty-two","thirty-three","thirty-four","thirty-five","thirty-six","thirty-seven","thirty-eight","thirty-nine","forty","forty-one","forty-two","forty-three"])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBDsIwDAS/gnoCCU48B3FMiSWUVMG09PWh9q4Ll3jHUdxxp1VzLdfepyZFj7ehljScB12qnbklo7G@mxWZjV7ysTPNqWw1ySPrVovgIZpP3uqSnv5IszRN3rNpEWVEOthUNn0ys09HtA8wblOLrnu4hLMD1QncgMhFgrAPCWsF/PwNY0li7Go7rXsIDUD8QUBoAEODJPPfHTUIoQHcNYDUGCssvFICGQ7MrnA/9f4F)

---

### Scoring and rules

For each language, the person whose code counts the highest wins. In case of a tie, the person who submitted first wins.

- No modules, libraries, builtins that convert from numeric to word form are allowed.
- You must output all integers from 1 (one) to n (your score) without missing any. If you want to output 0 (zero) as well, that's fine.
- You are allowed up to 500 bytes of code. Your code may be a full program or function.
- **Number format**: for consistency, all numbers must match the output of [this site](https://lingojam.com/NumbersToWords).
- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) (of course)
- [Standard output rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Come on, you could at least make your example better by just using a single space-separated string ;) but nice challenge! :)

Comment: Alternate title: `How high can you count in English?`

Comment: *You may, however, omit "and" if you'd like.* do we have to omit *and* or not? Personally, I'd say you wouldn't as it 'sounds more correct'.

Comment: @StepHen changed, thanks.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer my question. *Do we have to omit* and *or not?*

Comment: @Okx I take your point. Removed.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds to existing number-to-english challenges like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16217/20260) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54210/20260). Past getting the same basic pattern of digits down, the question seems to be how many prefixes for powers of 1000 one can compress into the remaining bytes.

Comment: Off the jokes, what if I can count to infinity?

Comment: @courtois I don't see how that would be possible, but I guess you'd win

Comment: @rosslh yeah you're right, I just saw the sentence `Number format: for consistency, all numbers must match the output of [this](https://lingojam.com/NumbersToWords) site.` And for my method, it would have been with `million of billion of billion of` ... though the site stops at `one hundred novenonagintanongentillion`, something like 3002 zeros.

Answer (score 3):

**Challenge: Count integers 1 to 10, but slowly on a time delay.**

Your challenge is to print the integers 1 to 10 to the screen with each integer separated by a newline, but on a time delay, such that it should take “n” seconds before the integer “n” is printed to the screen. For example, the program will wait 1 second before printing 1 and a newline, and then the program will wait 2 seconds before print 2 and a newline, and then the program will wait 3 seconds before print 3 and a newline.

So the expected standard output to the screen is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But the program will patiently wait “n” seconds before printing the integer “n” to the screen, so as your program may interpret it as …

waiting 1 second …

```
1
```

waiting 2 seconds …

```
2
```

waiting 3 seconds …

```
3
```

, and so on …

Restrictions:

**1)** Since some programming languages may not have a sense of system time, you are not allowed to use any modules/libraries/functions which can measure the time of your program within your program. Therefore all programming languages can be used. This restriction puts all the programming languages on an equal level.

**2)** Restriction 1 makes it such that you are required to write a function which takes about 1 second to process, and then you can rerun that function “n” integer of times before printing the next integer “n” in 1 to 10 to the screen. You can call your function whatever you want or if you can get away without naming the function then you can do that, too. So, your program would see this behind the scenes:

performing function fx 1 time. #which the arbitrary function fx takes about 1 second to process.

```
1
```

performing function fx 2 times

```
2
```

performing function fx 3 times

```
3
```

… and so on

**3)** Therefore, your program should take about 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 … + 10 = 55 seconds to finish printing all the integers from 1 to 10 to the screen. Since you need to write a function that takes about 1 second to process, acceptable solutions can be off by plus or minus 2 seconds from 55 seconds.

**4)** You must time your script which counts the integers 1 to 10 on a delay, so you can use any external program to time your script. I recommend using the bash function time, and giving me the “real” time or actual elapsed time of your script in seconds. If you time your script another way, tell me how you did it. Give me three digits after the decimal place for the real time in seconds. Do not round or truncate.

**winning condition:**

The winning condition is the fastest program in terms of actual elapsed real time in seconds which is closest to 55 seconds. If, for example, one submission is 54.9 seconds and another is 55.1 seconds, the 55.1 second submission wins because 54.9 seconds is too fast. Again, the point of this program is to slowly print integers to the screen.

Again, it should take approximately 55 +/- 2 seconds to print the integers 1 to 10 to the screen.

Comment: I modified my problem in such a way that no programming language should have an advantage.

Comment: `you are not allowed to use any modules/libraries/functions which can measure the time of your program` Does this mean things like `Stopwatch`, getting the `DateTime`, `Thread.Sleep`, etc?

Comment: Nice challenge by the way but I'm not sure I like the winning condition. What's wrong with a [tag:code-golf]? Also if I was you I'd trim some of the fluff down, at the moment there is a lot of text to information.

Comment: Will this not also vary dependent on what machine is running it? I really like the idea but I can imagine it being quite hard to test - especially with that winning condition, as I can imagine it coming down to hundredths of seconds, which would doubtlessly vary depending on the computer running it. Really like the idea nonetheless

Comment: I suppose you could do it by only running them on TIO? TIO's time limit is 60 seconds so you'll have ample time, & it should be a bit more uniform in terms of processing time.

Comment: Yes, TheLethalCoder you would not be allowed to do that. After I thought about, I realize that different computers may have different specifications for runtimes, although I suppose the winning condition could be the least number of bytes, but I was thinking about setting the winning condition to the fastest program which is closest to 55 seconds because if somebody wrote a program which had less bytes, but it was 1.9 seconds over 55 seconds, then it might be too slow for a lot of the other programs which had more bytes, but were faster.

Comment: Although if I set the winning condition to the least number of bytes, then I believe that I would have to increase the restraint to acceptable programs cannot be off by +/- 1 second from 55 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

## Random number from 0 to n

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that, given **a positive integer n**, outputs a **uniformly random integer from 0 to n**.

#### Input

- Input will be a **positive (non-zero) integer**.
- It will be in your language's number handling capabilities. // reword

#### Output

- Output must be a **uniformly (pseudo)random integer**.
- Every integer in the range **[0, n)** must have an **equal chance of being outputted**.
- You may assume that your chosen language's built-in RNG is uniform.
- Must be in **0 to n, in [0, n), ≥ 0 and < n**

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that perform this task are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

### Test cases

Note that this challenge is tagged [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) and hence will have non-deterministic outputs.

Incoming!

---

## Sandbox

- We *seriously* don't have this already?!

Comment: Interesting idea, but how will the test cases work? Also I imagine builtins will be the shortest for many languages

Comment: @Chris_Rands not all challenges need test cases.

Comment: Definition of random? We don't have it because it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Chris_Rands They're going to be random test cases. :P And yes, built-ins, but I'm afraid I don't like banning built-ins.

Comment: @feersum Yeah, I have to iterate over that better. Basically, it has to be uniformly pseudo-random. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork If you do find a dupe, please let me know! I've searched everywhere and asked in chat, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: [Extremely closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111613/42963)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Aha, I didn't find that (probably because it isn't tagged with [tag:number] :P). It's very close but it has some arbitrary restrictions... Good enough to have a regular one?

Comment: The only way an answer can be valid here and fail the "*arbitrary restrictions*" there is if it's a trivial call to a built-in, so this question doesn't add anything to the site.

Comment: Now define pseudorandom. Also, using a hardware random generator is not allowed?

Comment: @feersum I am not sure how much more I can define "random". I have edited in the fact that you can assume that your language's RNG is uniform. Where have I disallowed hardware random generators?

Comment: `it has to be uniformly pseudo-random` Pseudorandom is not random.

Comment: So now the only definition of "random" we have is that built-ins that are designated as random number generators are considered "random". So the challenge can *only* be answered by builtins, since there is no other definition provided.

Comment: @totallyhuman What if the language has a built-in RNG which is not a uniform RNG?

Answer (score 3):

## Case Matching Find Replace

Take three inputs, a string of text, `T`; a string of characters to replace, `F`; and a string of characters to replace them with, `R`. For each substring of `T` with the same (case insensitive) characters as `F`, replace them with the characters in `R`. However, keep the same case as the original text.

If there are more characters in `R` than `F`, the extra characters should be the same case as they are in `R`. If there are numbers or symbols in `F`, then the corresponding characters in `R` should keep the case they have in `R`. `F` will not necessarily appear in `T`.

You can assume all text will be in the printable ASCII range.

## Examples

```
"Text input", "text", "test" -> "Test input"

"tHiS Is a PiEcE oF tExT", "is", "abcde" -> "tHaBcde Abcde a PiEcE oF tExT"

"The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks", "o", " OH MY " -> "The birch can OH MY e slid  OH MY n the sm OH MY  OH MY th planks"

"The score was 10 to 5", "10", "tEn" -> "The score was tEn to 5"

"I wrote my code in Brain$#@!", "$#@!", "Friend" -> "I wrote my code in BrainFriend"

"This challenge was created by Andrew Piliser", "Andrew Piliser", "Martin Ender" -> "This challenge was created by Martin Ender"

// Has a match, but does not match case 
"John does not know", "John Doe", "Jane Doe" -> "Jane does not know"

// No match
"Glue the sheet to the dark blue background", "Glue the sheet to the dark-blue background", "foo" -> "Glue the sheet to the dark blue background"

// Only take full matches
"aaa", "aa", "b" -> "ba"

// Apply matching once across the string as a whole, do not iterate on replaced text
"aaaa", "aa", "a" -> "aa"
```

Comment: Example(s) where the replacement string narrowly does not appear in the text might help.

Comment: @isaacg Added one, let me know if it's not what you were thinking

Comment: What is the expected output for `"aaa","aa","b"` and `"aaaa","aa","a"`?

Comment: Will we guaranteed that `F` will appear at least once in `T`?

Comment: @Shaggy `F` will not necessarily appear in `T`.

Comment: @fireflame241 Added your two examples, good catch.

Comment: I would personally appreciate some kind of note on test case 3. It took me quite a while to realize that `John Doe` actually appears in full in the input string, rather than requiring we be able to replace all instances of `John` with `Jane` in that situation.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Added explanation for that case and a few others. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

## n-gon in m-gon

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

What is the greatest equilateral triangle you can fit into a regular pentagon? This is what this challenge is about, but with regular n-gons/m-gons.

#### Challenge

Given two integers `m,n` greater or equal to 3, find the maximal ratio of the areas of the two polygons such that the `m`-gon is completely contained in the `n`-gon.

#### Details

We are always talking about regular polygons, this means that all sides have the same length and all vertices are on a circle. The output can be a floating point-, fixed point- or rational number and must be correct to three decimal places.

#### Examples

```
 m  n  ratio (area m-gon / area n-gon)
 x  x  1 (for all x)
 3  4  1/4*sqrt(3) = 0.4330
 4  3  12/(7*sqrt(3)+12) = 0.4974
 3  6  1/2 = 0.5
 6  3  2/3 = 0.6667
```

Would be nice to have larger examples.

Comment: You may consider changing the language of the initial problem specification and input/output chart to specify that you are comparing the areas of the m- and n- gons

Comment: I see what you mean but right now I have difficulty coming up with a better wording (english is not my native language), if you have a better suggestion feel free to directly edit it!

Answer (score 3):

## Got Your PIN!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

I bet I can write down your PIN! 0000 0001 0002 0003 ... 9999.

### Task: Write a program that outputs a string containing all possible four digit PINs.

The string should not contain any whitespace (trailing newline is okay).

### Score: Length of program (in bytes) + length of output.

### Explanation

The output string only needs to contain each PIN somewhere in it; digits can be reused. For instance the string “123456789” contains the PINs 1234, 2345,3456,4567,5678,and 6789. By reusing digits, it's possible to save a significant amount of space from the naive implementation (0000000100020003...9999).

At best, this could be written as a 10,003 digit string. 4 digit for the first PIN, then one more digit for the other 9999 PINs.

### Testing your code

I've written a basic Python script that can check your solution and indicate any PINs you are missing.

```
import sys
s = sys.stdin.readline()
passes = True
for ix in range(10000):
    pin = "%04d" % (ix)
    if s.find(pin) == -1:
        print("Missing PIN %s" % pin)
        passes = False

if passes:
    print('Result passes!')
print('String length is %d characters.' % len(s))
```

Comment: Nice, but I think you need to replace [tag:code-golf] with [tag:code-challenge] as this isn't just scored by shortest code.

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13088/71256)

Comment: This is just https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42728/194 with hard-coded input, and hence qualifies as a dupe.

Comment: Too bad it's a duplicate... but now I know about De Bruijn sequences!

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I think there's one even more dupey than that; I've been trying to find it all day. The "background" to it was a keypad on a building door that had a 4-digit code.

Answer (score 3):

## Signed exponentiation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

Let us define *signed exponentiation* of a base **x** to a power **n** as this procedure:

1. Take the absolute value of **x**.
2. Raise to the power of **n**.
3. Re-apply the original sign of **x**.

Or, for a more mathematical (albeit slightly flawed) definition:

[image: the absolute value of x, to the power of n - 1, times x]

For this challenge, we will denote the signed exponentiation of **x** to **a** as **x ' a**. Some notes:

- Unlike **f(x) = x<sup>a</sup>**, **f(x) = x ' a** is defined for negative **x** no matter the value of **a**.
- The negative portion of the graph of **x ' n** is the positive portion rotated halfway about the origin; hence, **f(x) = x ' a** is an [odd function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions) for all values of **a**.
- If **a** is odd, **x ' a = x<sup>a</sup>** for all values of **x**.
- **x ' 1 = x**, while **x ' -1 = 1 / x**. **x ' 0** is a sign function (**+1** for positive **x**, **-1** for negative **x**).

### Challenge

Given a base **x** and a power **n**, compute **x ' n**.

#### Rules

- You may assume that **-9 ≤ x, n ≤ +9**.
- You may assume that **x ≠ 0**, for the sake of avoiding **0 ' 0**, **0 ' -1**, etc.
- You may assume that **1e-4 ≤ |x ' n| ≤ 1e9**.
- The output must be precise to at least 3 significant digits for the given test cases.
- Input/output may be taken/given in any standard format.

#### Test cases

```
x, n -> output
1, 0 -> 1
3.14159, 0 -> 1
-9, 0 -> -1
7, 1 -> 7
-1.23456, 1 -> -1.23456
5, 2 -> 25
-4, 3 -> -64
0.1, 4 -> 0.0001
-9, 9 -> -387420489
1, -1 -> 1
-3, -1 -> -0.33333
5, -2 -> 0.04
2.71828, -9 -> 0.0001234
4, 0.5 -> 2
-2, 0.5 -> -1.41421
2, -0.5 -> 0.7071
3.8236, -1.6702 -> 0.10645
0.1, -9 -> 1000000000
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes in each langauge wins.**

---

## Sandbox questions

- Could the definition be improved?
- Too many test cases? Are there any important ones missing?
- Any issues with the rules?

Comment: This isn't a huge deal, but I find the "your answer must be accurate to x significant figures" to be a largely unobservable property. The only ways to know that a submission meets this criterium is to check each and every possible combination, or to give an incredibly complex proof. I've always thought it was better to say floating point errors don't matter and to use loopholes otherwise. Maybe just a small thing about having to be able to represent any of the numbers from **1e-4** to **1e9**?

Comment: Thanks @FryAmTheEggman; I like your suggestion, but I'm afraid if it's not objective enough it'll cause any issues. Any suggestions on how to phrase it?

Comment: Perhaps have a few special test cases where they have to match the first three sig figs, and put in a line that those can't be hard coded. Then otherwise floating point errors don't matter? I'm honestly unsure. I've been getting to the point where I want to ask on meta because it always feels like fp questions are unclear or unobservable.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hopefully a little more objective now.

Comment: I think this looks much better, but there are perhaps too many "mandatory" test cases? Maybe making a split will make it easier for people to check the validity of answers.

Comment: Am I allowed to print more than 3 sigfigs?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Of course. Should be slightly clarified now

Comment: The way to prevent hardcoding is to have hidden test cases.

Comment: @user202729 Not sure I understand. How could hard coding possibly be useful for this challenge?

Comment: "for the given test cases". Although, yes, normally it is not useful. Whether you think it's necessary is up to you, but I doubt anyone would do it.

Answer (score 3):

### Type the alphabet as fast as you can

Your task is to make a program that measures how fast you can type the letters of the English alphabet.

- The program shall only accept lowercase letters `a` to `z` in alphabetical order.
- Each letter is echoed as typed on the same line (without new line or any other separators between letters).
- If you type an invalid character the program shall output `Fail` and exit.
- If you type all 26 letters the program shall output the time in milliseconds it took from the first to the last letter and exit.
- The timer starts when you type the first letter, `a`.

Example outputs:

```
b
Fail

abcdefgg
Fail

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
6440
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/build-a-typing-speed-test-measuring-cpm). I would also recommend to put "time" in some way into the title.

Comment: Thanks @Laikoni

Comment: Does the output have to be strictly in milliseconds, or at least in milliseconds, e.g. nanoseconds. Many builtin timing functions are in ns these days.

Answer (score 3):

## Stable modular exponents

[coge-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coge-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

It is well-known that the final three digits of [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) are 387. This is because Graham's number is a ridiculously tall exponent tower of threes: `3^(3^(3^...)))`, and it can be shown that any such tower of height at least 5 has 387 as its final three digits.

This generalises: given any base `n` and any starting number `a`, the exponent tower `a^(a^(a^...)))` will eventually stabilize modulo `n`. After that point, whatever you put in the topmost exponent, be it just a last `a`, or a continuation of the exponent tower (i.e. more than one `a`), or any other number, its congruency class modulo `n` will not change. That is the challenge that I set before you here today.

### Problem statement

Write a program or a function that takes two numbers `a` and `n` (within your language's standard signed or unsigned integer range) as input, and outputs the limit `l` of the sequence `a%n, (a^a)%n, (a^(a^a))%n,...`, which can be mathematically proven to be eventually constant (and therefore have a well-defined limit).

Your program should be able to handle `a > n` (note that `a` and `a+n` doesn't necessarily give the same result), and we require that `0 <= l < n`.

Warning: Reducing the exponents mudulo `n`, i.e. calculating this sequence recursively using `b[0] = a%n, b[i] = (a^b[i-1])%n` will yield the wrong result, and might not stabilize.

### Test cases

If we call the function `f(a, n)`, it should give the following:

```
> f(3, 1000)
387
> f(6, 10)
6
> f(5, 9)
2
> f(14, 9)
4
> f(3, 81)
0
```

### Scoring criteria

Standard code golf rules, use as few bytes as possible.

Answer (score 3):

## [The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops)

Comment: I would say posting the challenge separately for cops and for robbers with cross-referencing links will be better, because posting robbers' answers to the cops' thread is a bit obfuscating I think, and it seems to be the general method to post a C&R.

Comment: For the languages on Try it Online!, what's to stop me from trying to run a cops submission on every language there? Doesn't that put all those languages at a disadvantage?

Comment: Same concern as @KSmarts. With the C&R challenges where it is instead the code is hidden it's hard to crack answers because there are a large amount of possible programs they could have written (naively) but there are a relatively small number of languages so people could just try them all. I feel like there could be some added rules to get around this but I don't know what they'd be

Comment: So basically it is possible but impractical to try all of the languages on TIO.

Comment: @KSmarts Good point. As DLosc pointed out, changing the time restriction to, say, 5 minutes would most likely handle it.

Comment: @DLosc 1) Unary output seems perfectly acceptable, I'll edit it in. 2) I think allowing arbitrary starting and ending delimiters is a good idea 3) non-standard flags are flags that aren't required to run the program. Although, in hindsight, a better idea would be to allow flags but the answer has to state which flags are used. 4) Thanks for pointing that out, editing now.

Comment: @DLosc Edited in

Comment: The character limit for PPCG answers has been bumped to 65,536. Also, not that *printable ASCII* excludes newlines.

Answer (score 3):

## Voronoi Iteration

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given a finite set of points in the plane, output the set vertices of the corresponding Voronoi diagram.

#### Details

A vertex of the voronoi diagram is a point of the plane that has the same distance to the three or more closest input points.
As usual, you don't have to worry about the rounding issues of limited precision floating point numbers.

#### Examples

```
[(0,0),(2,0),(0,2),(2,2)] -> [(1,1)]
[(0,0),(1,0)] -> []
[(0,0),(2,0),(0,2)] -> [(1,1)]
```

Inspired by [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291208/a-voronoi-iteration-game).

Comment: I suggest having a test case with floating point coordinates.

Comment: (although I already understood the test cases) it would be helpful to have an image.

Comment: @user202729 It definitely needs more examples, but you can obviously interpret these coordinates as floating points as well.

Comment: Having a test case with floating point coordinates will help testing if programs handle floating point input correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## Number rewinder

Inspired by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584084/how-to-move-the-first-digit-to-the-end-of-a-number-in-c/48589774#48589774) and little bit expanded.

Your task is to rotate left a given integer by one digit in a given base and return integer (move the MSD to the LSD position).

Input: Two integers `Number > Base > 1`
Output: `Result`

Test cases:

```
Number Base  Result  String representations
61453   10    14536  61453 -> 14536
61453   16      223  F00D -> DF (00DF)
61453    8   229481  170015 -> 700151
60429   16    49374  EC0D -> C0DE
62977   16    24607  F601 -> 601F
```

This is Code-golf, standard loopholes are forbidden and shortest answer wins.

Comment: I don't think your restriction about strings is going to work out well, there's not really a way to verify strings aren't being used. In any case, string rotation isn't that much different from the arithmetic required to do this operation. Personally, I'd recommend just allowing them. Thanks for using the sandbox!

Comment: (i.e., we don't like do X without Y or unobservable behavior)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman If there isn't some `ToString`-like function that opperates on any base using strings may be more difficult than dealing with it numerically.

Comment: I've never heard "*rewind*" used with this meaning before. I would call that operation "*rotation left*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for suggestion. I've updated bounds for the inputs to avoid rotating 1 digit "number"

Answer (score 3):

How acceptable is it to base challenges off of pre-existing challenges? I saw the challenge for [Your Own Pet Ascii Snake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156245/code-golf-your-own-pet-ascii-snake) and had a thought about making the output look more 'snakelike' by printing the characters |,\,/,(,),_ instead of always using the + character.

Here's how it would work. You would get some positive, negative, and 0 numbers as input, and based on those numbers, the snake moves one row down and that many characters in that direction. So, for a snake like the ones in the previous problem, your array would be restricted to the numbers 0, 1, and -1.

Here are the rules to draw the snake, the characters you print are dependent on the spacing of the lines before and after it.

So, say your snake is at position n (in the previous problem, n=30 to start, in this one you need to figure out a number for n that will keep your entire snake on the screen),

if the input is 0 you print n-1 spaces and a `|`
if the input is +1 you print n spaces and a `\`
if the input is +2 you print n spaces and `\_`, +10 would be `\_________` (9 `_` and a backslash)
if the input is -1 you print n-2 spaces and  `/`
if the input is -2 you print n-3 spaces and `_/`, -10 would be `_________/`

Here's an example snake based on this array `[+4, -3, +1, -4, +2, -3, +2, +5, -4, -1, -2, 0, +4, -4]`

```
                        |
                         \___
                          __/
                          \
                       ___/
                       \_
                      __/
                      \_
                        \____
                        ____/
                       /
                     _/
                    |
                     \___
                     ___/
```

I could also add optional 'curvy' rules that would include the '(' and ')' characters on direction changes to produce a snake like this, based on the same array above:

```
                         |
                         \___
                          ___)
                         (_
                       ____)
                      (__
                      ___)
                     (__
                        \____
                        _____)
                       /
                     _/
                    (
                     \___
                     ____)
```

note that for the curvy snake, 0s are handled differently depending on if there is a direction change in the rows above and below them, here there is a negative, 0, positive pattern, so we use a '(', if there were no direction change we'd use a |, and in the opposite pattern, a ')'

There are spaces to the left of my example snake because I didn't want to count out how many spaces I should leave exactly, I don't know whether it should be mandatory to cut out extra whitespace to the left, or whether to let people have as much or as little whitespace as they want, provided that their snake doesn't 'go off screen'

Comment: I don't think there's a problem determining the next line randomly. For example, my program could generate the numbers for all 30 lines and then go back and format the characters appropriately. However, I'm not sure that's different enough to warrant its own challenge. Your second idea, though, regarding taking +1/-1/0 as input, that has some merit as it's pretty radically different than the existing snake challenge.

Comment: I'm far, far too tired for you to rely on my opinion alone but this looks sufficiently different enough from the 2 existing challenges to not be a dupe, once it's fleshed out a bit more. I'd suggest waiting a while before posting it, though, as people do get jaded of a barrage of similarly themed challenges.

Answer (score 3):

## Universal Self-correcting Program

The idea here is to make a program that can tolerate errors **in its own code**, while still functioning correctly.

Since "error" is too broad, we will define it by a single bit flip. Of course, more tolerant versions, that could accept swapping any character with any other character would still be valid.

This program is **universal** in the sense that you can write any other self-correcting program (with the same tolerance) -- more on that later.

Importantly:

> 1) This program takes as input a triple-redundancy string of characters, and outputs a corrected string.
>
> 2) This program executes correctly with any bit flip in its own code.

## (1) Triple redundancy codes

A triple redundancy code consists of simply repeating each bit, character or byte 3 times. In this case we use characters.

Correction is done by taking the majority of the characters, so (A,A,B) is corrected to *A*, (A,B,B) is corrected to *B* and so on.

```
AAA => A
AAB => A
HHHEEELLXLLLXOO => HELLO
```

This is a very crude an inefficient code for correcting single bit errors, but it is the least complex, which is why I think may be the best choice here. Hamming codes are better but a little more complex.

## (2) Error tolerance

Our program will be defined as error tolerant if it performs the desired decoding function for any single bit flip in its own code. It may take longer for some inputs or when some flips occur, but it should always terminate.

## Putting it together

The error-tolerant program can receive as input a (possibly faulty) program, and outputs a error-free program. Therefore, if a single-bit error occurs anywhere in the system comprised of (decoder,input program), a corrected program will still be output.

## Observation

I don't actually know if this is possible, quite possibly it won't be achievable in every language. If it is too hard, we may relax the tolerable errors.

## Scoring

The score will reflect the reliability of your program to errors. `Tolerance` is simply the number of bit flips you code accepts anywhere. It must be at least 1 (accept 1 bit flip anywhere). `Size` is the length of your program in bytes.

The score is `Score = Size / 2^Tolerance`

Lowest score wins.

[error-correction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction) [coding-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory) [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

**Note**: Several other challenges are possibly solved by solving this one (which would make sense given its universality!) by hardcoding the input.

> [Detect if your program has been mutated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107643/detect-if-your-program-has-been-mutated)
>
> [Write a program that always outputs “2012” - even if it's modified!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/write-a-program-that-always-outputs-2012-even-if-its-modified)

This solves the "Who Watches the Watchmen?" problem involved in error correcting programs, like in this challenge:

> [Meta radiation hardener](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111005/meta-radiation-hardener)

since the decoding program itself tolerates errors (what good would be an error correcting program that is itself in error? :p).

Comment: Check the [tag:radiation-hardening] tag for duplicates and rules clarifications, too.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. It appears no one has proposed a *Universal* radiation hardener yet (this is universal only in the sense of bit flip errors; those are actually a good model for radiation though!).

Comment: Again Lenguage win lol

Comment: Even though your scoring involves code length you should use [tag:code-challenge] instead of [tag:code-golf] for challenges that are not solely scored by code length.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I'm putting this challenge on the back burner for a indefinite time in favor of the [Hierarchies](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16435#16435) challenge. Go check that or the [Formic Forest](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16415#16415) out if you're interested in a Formic sequel.

---

## Formic Functions 3: Memory

*This is a preliminary write-up of a new challenge heavily inspired by [**Formic Functions**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/). The spec is based on the original challenge's spec - credits for most of what you'll read here to **[trichoplax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20283/trichoplax)**.*

Each player starts with one ant - a queen, who collects food. Each piece of food can be held or used to produce a worker. Workers also collect food to be brought back to the queen.

All players compete in one arena. The winner is the queen holding the most food after she has taken <s>8,000</s> 10,000 **[Thanks @Draco18s]** turns. Ants can communicate by changing the colors of the arena squares (which can also be modified by rivals), as well as by storing messages for their peers.

## The arena

The arena is a toroidal (edge wrapping) grid of hexagonal cells arranged in a rhombus of side length 1000. All cells start as color 1.

Initially exactly <s>1%</s> 0.5% of cells will contain food. The 5000 pieces of food will be scattered uniformly randomly. No new food will be introduced during the game.

The queens will be placed randomly on empty cells, with no guarantee that they will not be adjacent to each other (although this is very unlikely).

## Ant abilities

- **Sight:** Each ant sees the 7 cells in its neighborhood. It has no knowledge of any other ants outside this neighborhood. It sees the contents of each of the 7 cells (other ants and food), and also each cell's *color*.
- **Memory:** Each ant has access to a string as its memory. It is initially empty for the queen, and must be initialized by the queen when spawning a worker. For ways to change the memory after initialization, see **Output** below.
- **No orientation:** An ant does not know where it is or which way it faces - it has no concept of North. The neighborhood will be presented to it at a randomly rotated orientation that changes each turn so it cannot even walk in a straight line unless it has colors to guide it. *(Making the same move every turn will result in a random walk rather than a straight line.)*
- **Moving, color marking, producing workers and transferring food:** See **Output** below.
- **Immortality:** These are highland ants that cannot die. You can confuse rival ants by changing the colors around them, or constrain them from moving by surrounding them with 6 ants of your own, but they cannot be harmed apart from this. **[Should ants be able to die? If so, how?]**
- **Carrying food:** A worker can carry up to 1 piece of food. A queen can carry an arbitrary amount of food.

## Coding

#### Provide a function body

Each ant is controlled by an ant function. ***Each turn the player's ant function is called separately for each ant (not just once per player, but once for the queen and once for each worker that player controls).*** Each turn, the ant function will receive its input and return a move for that particular ant.

Post an answer containing a code block showing the body of a JavaScript function, and it will be automatically included in the controller. The name of the player forms the title of the answer, in the form `# PlayerName`.

#### No access to outside data

Functions must be fully deterministic. When called with a given input, they must return the same output every time. A function must not access global variables and must not store state between turns in other ways than through the provided memory string. It may use built in functions that do not involve storing state or accessing data from the outside. For example, the use of `Math.abs()` is fine, but `Date.getTime()`, `Math.random()` must not be used.

**An ant function may only use a pseudo random number generator that it supplies itself, that utilizes data provided through input.** For example, it may implement its own pseudo RNG via its memory string, seeded by the environment (or statically).

A simple random strategy is still possible due to the random orientation of the input - an ant that always chooses the same direction will perform a random walk rather than a straight line path.

An ant function is permitted to contain further functions within its body.

## Input and output

#### Input

The orientation of the input will be chosen at random for each ant and for each turn. The input will be rotated by 0, 60, 120, 180, 240 or 300 degrees, but will never be reflected.

Cells are numbered in this order:

```
 0 1
5 6 2
 4 3
```

The ant function will receive an array called `view`, containing an object for each of the 7 visible cells. Each object will have the following:

```
color: a number from 1 to 8
food: 0 or 1
ant: null if there is no ant on that cell, or otherwise an ant object
```

**[Is 8 colors perhaps too many?]**

If a cell contains an ant, the ant object will have the following:

```
food: 0 or more (maximum 1 for a worker)
queen: true or false
friend: true or false
memory: memory string when friendly, otherwise undefined
```

**[<s>Should ants be able to read rivals' memories?</s> This would cause rampant edit wars. Rejected.]**

The ant can determine its own details by looking at the ant in the central cell, `view[6].ant`. For example, `view[6].ant.memory` contains the memory of the executing ant.

#### Output

Output is returned as an object representing the action to take. This can have any of the following:

```
cell: a number from 0 to 6 (mandatory)
color: a number from 1 to 8 (optional)
spawn: a string (optional)
memory: a string (optional)
```

If `color` and `spawn` are omitted or non-[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then `cell` indicates the cell to move to.

If `color` is a number, the indicated cell is set to that number.

If `spawn` is a string, a worker ant is created on the indicated cell. The new worker will have its `memory` initialized to that string. The string cannot be longer than 256 characters. Only a queen can create a new worker, and only if she has food, as this costs one piece of food per worker.

If `memory` is a string, the executing ant will have its `memory` immediately changed to that string. The string cannot be longer than 65,536 characters for the queen, and 256 characters for workers. An ant may change its memory while also performing a different action - changing memory does not take a turn.

**[Should changing own memory take a turn?]**

**[Should ants be able to send a message directly to another ant's `inbox`? For example, a message could look like this: `{title:"help", content:view_array_of_sender}`. An ant should also be able to perform an action while sending a message, otherwise the described behavior could be emulated.]**

**[Should ants be able to see the age of an ant? This behavior will often be emulated with memory. Is there a reason *not* to do that?]**

**[<s>Is 65,536 characters a good number to pick for the max length of memory?</s> Thanks to @Draco18s's and @dzaima's advice, workers now have significantly less memory than a queen.]**

Example outputs:

```
{cell:0}: move to cell 0
{cell:5, memory:"abc"}: move to cell 5 and set own memory to "abc"
{cell:6}: move to cell 6 (that is, do nothing, as 6 is the central cell)
{cell:6, color:8}: set own cell to color 8
{cell:2, color:1, memory:"hey"}: set cell 2 to color 1 and set own memory to "hey"
{cell:1, spawn:"def", memory:"5252"}: create a worker with its memory initialized to "def" on cell 1 and set own memory to "5252"
{cell:3, color:0}: equivalent to just `{cell:3}` - move rather than set color
{cell:1, spawn:0}: equivalent to just `{cell:1}` - move rather than create worker
{cell:4, color:0, spawn:0}: move to cell 4 - color 0 and type 0 are ignored
```

Invalid outputs:

```
{cell:7}: cell must be from 0 to 6
{cell:0, color:9}: color must be from 1 to 8
{cell:0, spawn:true}: spawn must be a string
{cell:6, spawn:"254"}: cannot create a worker on a non-empty cell
{cell:0, color:1, spawn:"77"}: cannot set color and create worker in the same turn
{cell:3, memory:true}: cannot set memory to non-string
{cell:2, spawn:true}: cannot create a worker with a non-string memory
{cell:0, memory:long_string}: (if long_string is a string of length > 65536) cannot set memory to a string of length greater than 65536
```

**[Missed any?]**

An ant moving onto a cell containing food will automatically pick up the piece of food. If that ant is a laden worker, it will move onto the cell without picking up the piece of food.

An unladen worker trying to move onto an enemy queen with food will steal one piece of food from her instead. A laden worker trying to move onto an unladen friendly worker or a friendly queen will give its food to their target instead.

## Turn order

Ants take turns in a set order. At the start of a game the queens are assigned a random order which does not change for the rest of the game. When a queen creates a worker, that worker is inserted into the turn order at the position before its queen. This means that all other ants belonging to all players will move exactly once before the new worker takes its first turn.

## Limit on number of players

Obviously an unlimited number of players cannot fit into the arena. If there are more than 8 answers, only 8 of them will play in any one game.

**[Good max number of players?]**

## Time limit per turn

Each time the ant function is called, it should return within 20 milliseconds. Since the time limit may be exceeded due to fluctuations outside the ant function's control, an average will be calculated. If at any point the average is above 20 milliseconds and the total time taken by that particular ant function across all calls so far is more than 10 seconds, the relevant player will be disqualified.

**[Enough time?]**

## Disqualification

This means the player will not be eligible to win and their ant function will not be called again during that game. They will also not be included in any further games. If a player is disqualified on the tournament machine during a leaderboard game then it will be excluded from all future leaderboard games until edited.

A player will be disqualified for any of the following for any of its ants (queen or worker):

- Exceeding the time limit as described.
- Returning an invalid move as described under Output.
- The cell to move to contains an ant and the case isn't defined under Output.
- The cell to produce a worker on contains an ant.
- A worker is trying to produce a worker.

**[Did I miss any?]**

It may seem harsh to disqualify for invalid moves, rather than simply interpreting this as no move. However, I believe that enforcing correct implementations will lead to more interesting strategies over time. This is not intended to be an additional challenge, so a clear reason will be displayed when a player is disqualified, with the specific input and output alongside to aid in fixing the code.

## Multiple answers and editing

You may provide multiple answers, provided that they do not team up against the others. Provided each answer is working solely towards its own victory, you are permitted to tailor your strategy to take advantage of weaknesses in specific other strategies, including changing the color of the cells to confuse or manipulate them. Bear in mind that as more answers come in, the likelihood of meeting any particular player in a given game will diminish.

You may also edit your answers whenever you choose. It is up to you whether you post a new answer or edit an existing one. Provided the game is not flooded with many near-identical variations, there should be no problem.

If you make a variation of another person's answer, please remember to give them credit by linking to their answer from yours.

## Scoring

At the end of each game, a player's score is the number of other players who have less food carried by their queen. Food carried by workers is not counted. This score is added to the leaderboard, which is displayed in order of average score per game.

Joint places indicate that the order of players is not yet consistent between 6 subsets of the games played so far. The list of games is split into 6 subsets because this is the minimum number that will give a probability of less than 5% that a given pair of players will be assigned distinct places in the wrong order.

**[Scoring mechanism subject to change.]**

**[New feature/modification recommendations are very welcome! I want this challenge to be as different from the original Formic as possible, while keeping its spirit.]**

[hexagonal-grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid)
[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)
[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)
[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: 8000 turns is too few, 65k of memory is way too much.

Comment: I feel like the food density being so high is compensation enough for 8k moves. This was also chosen out of speed concerns - no caching like the previous Formic. 65k memory was designed as a "use all you want". I wanted to allow doing some crazy stuff, like storing large portions of the map. After some consideration, however, limiting this to for example 1k could be a good idea.

Comment: One thing that might make this challenge stand out would be if food "respawns" over time. That is, every N turns Y food is added to the board. Also, I still don't like the hex layout [for the reasons dzaima pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43270961#43270961).

Comment: That would encourage periodically re-searching parts of the board for more complex entries... It would be simple to do, considering you have a lot of memory, but... Isn't this just complexity tacked on for the sake of complexity? Hmm, I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Comment: I'd suggest that the queen has the 65k memory but the workers - maybe ~500. Also do consider that each character is (IIRC) 2 bytes as JS uses UTF-16

Comment: I was just thinking about more memory for the queen. Great idea!

Comment: Saying that a "grid of hexagonal cells" is "toroidal" and has a specific "height" and "width" is somewhat ambiguous. I *think* I understand now, but it bears some more detailed explanation.

Comment: Oh, good point. I thought it was obvious enough. I'll find a way to explain it better.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Is it clear enough now?

Answer (score 3):

The TI series of calculators. I've put a lot of hours in writing TI-BASIC programs. The single most tedious part was either scrolling through the program, or switching between alpha and numeric input.

For those unfamiliar, the entire Latin alphabet is overlaid on the existing keys alphabetically, and to type any of them (For variable names or assembly programming), you had to first press the ALPHA key, then your desired letter. Alternatively, you could press 2ND, A-LOCK and type in any number of letters, before pressing ALPHA again for numeric input.

Why am I saying all this? I want to write a code golf like challenge where scoring is done with this tediousness in mind, like switching between numbers/punctuation and letters carrying an extra penalty.

My original idea is that the source code of the submission would be converted to hexadecimal, and the number of transitions between alphas and numerics would be the "score," with a lower score being better.

How can/should I better refine this scoring system, and what sort of challenge should accompany it?

### The Challenge

Implement a program or function, in the language of your choice, that takes a string of characters as input and outputs that string's "tediousness score."

How tediousness is scored:

1. The string is converted into its hexadecimal representation. This is Unicode for languages that don't specify, but for a language like, say, Jelly, the Jelly codepage is used.
   `"The quick brown fox jumps, over the lazy dog's back." in Unicode == 0x54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d70732c206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f672773206261636b2e`
2. Each switch between numbers and letters in the hexadecimal representation is counted.
   `0x54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a...`
   `..0                12      34  56    78    9...`
3. This is your tediousness score. For this example, it is 25.

Standard loopholes apply.

Should I change the tediousness score? How might I implement golf? I thought about adding/multiplying the two together, but it still seemed to be in favor of just plain golfing. I wanted to make golfing languages be a bit harder for a golfing challenge, since they really pack their character sets and there would be a high "tediousness score".

Is the challenge, as written, clear enough? Should I restrict or relax the I/O requirements?

Comment: I have found that challenges with novel scoring mechanisms work nicely if the task is to implement the score calculator itself, see e.g. [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/unique-is-cheap).

Comment: Probably `tedious×log(nbytes)`?

Comment: What about giving a list of integers (byte values), or restricting the input to printable ASCII?

Comment: @user202729 Because I wanted entries to be scored by this method, and I didn't want to exclude esoteric golfing languages. I specifically want to include them, and make them hard to win with.

Comment: What about "the input is a byte string"? That way you don't need to worry about the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

> X1M4L got in before me and posted the very similar challenge [Print the previous answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161757/print-the-previous-answer), which I don't mind at all. However, that one seems to have turned out quite a lot more open-ended than this version would be, with answers tending to score in the tens of thousands. So after a sufficiently long delay this will probably not be considered a duplicate - I intend to leave it in the sandbox for at least a few months before posting.

## Compress the previous answer

This is an [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge. The first answer must output the empty string. The second answer must output the source code of the first answer, and so on, with each answer outputting the code of the previous one.

To make this challenging, no answer may be longer than 100 bytes in length. Once the answers start getting close to this limit, it will become necessary to compress the text of the previous answers, which itself will become harder over time.

Each answer should output the exact string of bytes that forms the previous program. Because of this, if your program is in any format other than plain ASCII, you should post a hexdump as well as the source, so that the next person knows exactly what to output.

An answer's score is its position in the chain, i.e. the `N`th answer scores `N` points. Your score is the score of your highest-scoring answer. You are encouraged to treat this challenge cooperatively, keeping the chain going as long as possible by not adding extra unnecessary entropy to your code.

The code of your answer cannot be identical to the code of any previous answer. The first answer must be at least one byte in length.

You may not post two consecutive answers. There are no restrictions on language.

tags: [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

Comment: that's so weird, I was thinking of this the other day, after seeing all those quine/answer chaining challenges.

Comment: You'd probably need to provide some non-empty seed, to prevent the answers from all being blank themselves. Also, would there be any restrictions on language choice - e.g. would each answer need to be in a different language than all those that came before?

Comment: @user56656 just position in the chain - I've added it

Comment: @Sok I've fixed the "all programs empty" issue by requiring each entry to be different from the previous one. I tend towards not putting restrictions on language choice (I've added that for now) but if there's a good argument for including such restrictions I'm open minded.

Comment: You should probably prevent source reading.  A pretty good strategy will to be to make a valid submission in language A that is also a period 2 quine in language B.  Alternatively, you might want to impose the restriction that new answers are different from *every* previous answer instead of just the last one.

Comment: Another consideration is whether consecutive answers should be permitted.  It is pretty common to put restrictions on individual answerers, to prevent schemes designed to game the system.

Comment: @user56656 I've implemented your idea about making them distinct from all previous answers, and I've banned consecutive answers by the same person. Does that cover all the bases?

Comment: I've also changed the length restriction to 100 (makes a shorter challenge, but the restriction will kick in sooner)

Comment: It might be prudent to try a test drive of the challenge (in chat) to test if the 100 byte limit is good.  I'd be willing to help with that. Other than that I have no further thoughts at this time.

Comment: @user56656 that makes sense - I'll try that when I have a chance (might be in a week or two).

Comment: I think you probably gain more from saying languages cannot be repeated (and including a stack snipped of used languages) than you do by adding a lot of workarounds for quines. I think it will cause the answers to become more interesting more quickly. It will also result in the challenge ending sooner, but given how the hello world answer chaining question went, I don't think you have too much to worry about with respect to longevity (though increasing the 100 may be a good idea if you decide to do this).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't think quines will be a problem in any case, because the Nth answer has to output a program that outputs a program that ... that outputs the empty string, so by definition it can't be a quine. That could be got around with polyglots, but I'd be very surprised if it would be an issue in practice - the criterion of not being identical to a previous answer is there to prevent quines not only in practice but also in theory!

Comment: The problem that I see is that if languages are repeatable you might get a really boring and repetitive sequence of 3-4 languages that somewhat trivialise the problem appearing quickly after each more interesting answer. I perhaps should have said "trivial modifications of near-quines" instead? Anyway, this may not happen, but I think you should focus on this as well when doing the short test run (i.e. check what portion of answers can be trivially followed by a /// or Bubblegum program).

Comment: How about making the maximum length of answer `n` a slowly growing function over `n`?

Comment: @Laikoni that's an interesting idea. I guess probably logarithmic would be good choice. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Never saw this when writing mine, but you're right; it's the same. You sure you don't want to claim it?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I really don't mind - it's a super busy time for me right now and I didn't want to post it until I'd done the 'dry run' mentioned in the comments above, but if you get yours done and posted before that it's really no problem for me at all. If there's any ideas in my version that you like, please feel free to steal them!

Answer (score 3):

## Inversion languages

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

### Cops

For this challenge you will design two languages, **A** and **B**.  Both **A** and **B** should be [Turing equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)<sup>1</sup>.  When run in your two languages a program has four options:

1. It halts in both **A** and **B**.
2. It halts in **A** but not **B**.
3. It halts in **B** but not **A**.
4. It doesn't halt in either **A** or **B**.

Your goal is to try to design **A** and **B** such that as many programs as possible halt in exactly one language (options 2 and 3).  Doing such for all programs is impossible<sup>2</sup>, thus there will always be programs that meet either criterion 1 or criterion 4.  The robbers will attempt to find these programs.

#### Further rules on languages

Since we are only considering whether programs halt or not we don't care about I/O.  Because of this programs should not take any input.  You may produce output but really doesn't matter because it can neither hurt nor help you.

All programs should be deterministic in both languages, this means that any program that can halt must always halt and any program that can run indefinitely must do so.

#### Answering

Your answer should contain the following information.

1. A concrete description of both languages
2. Proofs that each language as described is Turing complete.

Your definitions should be rigorous and unambiguous.  Meaning that a reasonable person should (given enough time) be able to workout the result of any computation.  This means all edge cases should be covered and there should be no undefined behavior.

#### Scoring

Your score will be the time between your post and the first crack with a higher score being better.

### Robbers

Robbers will score 1 point for every answer that they crack, with a higher score being better.

Your answers should include the program which cracks the cop's answer and a proof that it does.

### Sandbox

This is kind of just an idea right now.  I have to iron out a lot of details and I will.  I'll flesh it out later I just want to get it down so I don't forget it.  Right now the most useful feedback would be in broad strokes.  Don't worry about details, that's my job.

---

<sup>1: Turing equivalent is very similar to Turing completeness, but also stipulates that the language can be simulated by a Turing machine.  Turing complete languages are not Turing equivalent if they are incomputable.</sup>

<sup>2: Suppose that we did have two Turing complete languages **A** and **B** such that every program halted in exactly one of the languages.  We could solve the halting problem in language **A** by running a program in both **A** and **B** on separate threads until one of them halted, then outputting whether it was **A** or not.</sup>

Comment: +1, very nice idea. But "to maintain fairness, this challenge will only be open to submissions for one week after the first cop's answer is posted" doesn't make sense to me - it seems to make it *less* fair, by preventing anyone from competing who comes across the challenge late or just spends time on their submission.

Comment: @Nathaniel The problem is that answers are scored based on how long they last answers that are late to the party have a huge advantage, since people won't be monitoring the challenge as much the older it gets.  I would *love* to have a challenge that is open indefinitely, I strive to make that for all my challenges, so if anyone can think of a objective winning criterion that allows for this I'm all ears.

Comment: I see, hmm, that makes sense even if it's unsatisfying. Nothing comes to mind as an alternative scoring mechanism for this challenge for now.

Comment: A separate point: I wonder if this might be a bit hard for the cops. Off the top of my head, I find it hard to think of a way to design two languages such that it wouldn't be obvious how to crack it. This might just be a failure of my imagination, however!

Comment: What do you mean with _input [a program] into your two languages_? Is this about polyglots? If so, how would you consider programs which are syntax errors in one or both of the languages?

Comment: @Leo Input should probably be replaced with the verb "*run*".  This is about polyglots.  This is one of the things I plan on expanding on later on, but I'll either disallow syntax errors or consider them to be halting.

Comment: Maybe avoid encrypting? (If key doesn't match, A always halt and B never halt; you hve no key lol

Comment: but once known turing complete it's usually easily converted to an ans

Comment: Although languages A and B such that all programs halt in exactly one language is impossible, A and B such that can't find one is possible

Comment: With respect to @Nathaniel's observation about "only open for a week", it's certainly true that one of the problems of C'n'R is that the robbers get bored or don't notice late cop submissions, but it's not clear what "open to submissions" means. You're surely not thinking of asking the mods to lock the question, so you can't stop people posting new submissions. Perhaps that would be better rephrased in terms of when you will award the "accepted answer".

Comment: The issue of testability is also a big one. If B is something along the lines of "Run the program through A for N steps. If it terminates, enter an infinite loop. Otherwise take the parts which are comments in language A and run them." Tune N so that it takes about a week to get any program to terminate in B.

Comment: @l4m2 I would rather not ban encrypting because I consider it an unenforcable restriction.  As you pointed out proving an answer to be Turing complete becomes a large hurdle for cops to overcome if they choose to cryptography.  For example it is unknown whether Malbodge Unshackled is TC.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I suppose you are correct.  I won't be accepting an answer so I suppose I can't do anything to discourage new answers.  I also don't think test-ability is that big of an issue, most work here will be mathematical rather than testing individual programs.  For example to crack the languages you describe you just need to find a program in B that runs for over N steps.  That's a pretty straightforward busy beaver problem. Robbers will likely have to include proofs that their programs behave as they claim (especially if they claim they don't halt).

Comment: Will [bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum)-like language win the game?

Comment: @tsh bubblegum is not known to be TC so it would be an invalid submission.

Comment: @user56656 I mean bubblegum like, e.g. calculate checksum for first line, and execute the second line for different checksum. Or other way which may make almost impossible to write any program in the language.

Comment: @tsh The problem with bubblegum or similar languages is that crypto functions are designed to be really hard to predict. This makes it hard to say anything concrete about their behavior, which in turn makes any language that uses them in a non-trivial manner, *really* hard to prove TC. TCness means it is possible to write a program for every Turing machine, and since it is almost impossible to write a program in the language it is hard to show that every program can be written. I would recommend trying to come up with a language pair that has these properties. You might run into some issues.

Comment: Is _undefined behavior_ considered to be always halt or never halt? For example, we define two language A, B: if first letter in source code is lower case `[a-z]`, A interpret it by Python 2.7, otherwise it is undefined behavior in A; if first letter in source code is upper case `[A-Z]`, B interpret it by Python 2.7, otherwise it is undefined behavior in B. As the result, one cannot write a program which both run on A and B without undefined behavior.

Comment: @tsh There is no such thing as undefined behavior.

Comment: Another couple of related questions: (1) to what extent does the interpreter have to meet the spec? Obviously it can't meet it completely, since the interpreter runs on a finite machine with finite addressing, and therefore can't technically be Turing complete. What about cases like integer overflow? (2) How would you handle bugs in the interpreter, and/or ambiguities in the spec?

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm not sure it's something I've been thinking about quite a bit.  I want the specification to be rigorously defined (that is unambiguous), but I don't want to be very strict about interpreters.  My thought is to go with a rule like "your interpreter must work for as many cases as is reasonable", giving some slack to users, and then require them to include the ways in which the interpreter violates the spec (e.g. uses `long` to represent an integer).  If you have any specific thoughts on these questions I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: One possible option is not to require an interpreter at all. The advantage is that it forces the spec to be precise enough to implement, and if it's not the robbers will naturally ask for clarification rather than relying on the implementation. It also lowers the barrier to entry for cops. However, it does raise the amount of work the robbers need to do --- but not necessarily by that much, since I suspect that cracking these will mostly be about logical deduction rather than being a computational task. (I'm not 100% sure about that last point though.)

Answer (score 3):

Really skirting bit of sandboxing here (I haven't taken the time to develop the question):

I'd like to do a 2-d variant of this one.

[Two lasers between two mirrors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161632/two-lasers-between-two-mirrors)

The input would be an ascii maze, with a marker for the laser starting point, e.g.:

```
+---+------+
|*  |      |
|   |      |
|   |  ----+
|   |      |
|   |      |
|   |      |
|   +---   |
|          |
|          |
|          |
+----------+
```

- Astrisk(*): laser starting point.
- Whitespace: passable.
- Any other character is a reflective obstacle.

Result:

```
+---+------+
|\  |   /\ |
| \ |  /  \|
|  \| /----+
|  /|/   /\|
| / |\  / /|
|/  | \/ / |
|\  +---/  |
| \    /   |
|  \  /    |
|   \/     |
+----------+
```

Rules:

- When you can't move horizontally, reverse horizontal direction.
- When you can't move vertically, reverse vertical direction.
- Stop going when you meet the same laser coming the other way (e.g. when you hit a corner or reach your starting position again).I'm thinking of a golfing challenge.
- If the laser revisits a space in the other direction, draw an upper case X.

Simplifying factors:

- Let's just say the laser always goes the same way.
- The map is always a rectangle.
- Just the one laser.

It'll probably just be a golfing challenge.

Comment: What's the goal of the program, just to draw the path? Food for thought, if you wanted a related but different challenge you could include a "start" and "goal" marker, and make the program determine if the laser ever hits the goal, returning "true" or "false" instead of a drawn maze. Or perhaps it should return *how many steps* it takes to hit the goal, returning either an integer, or a falsy value if it never hits it? Up to you, but some ideas.

Comment: Consider removing the outside wall.  You say that the laser always goes in the same direction, but I think that you should explicitly say that it always starts heading south-east (or down-right).  Important test cases:  All of the walls aren't connected to the border. Laser hits a 1-length wall.  Laser crosses itself.  Laser hits a + (on the inside).  Laser barely misses a +.  Laser starts next a right wall.  Laser starts next to bottom wall.  Laser starts at a bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 3):

## Rebuild My Scrabble Board

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

My daughter and I have an ongoing Scrabble tournament. We enjoy admiring the board at the end of a game. But recently we knocked over the board and didn't get a chance to get a good look or take a picture. Fortunately, we kept track of all our moves. Your challenge is to take the list of moves and use it to rebuild the Scrabble board.

### Input

Each move includes 4 pieces of information

1. Column - `A` - `O`, like the column label of a typical spreadsheet. Upper or lower case is OK, but you only need to support one or the other.
2. Row - `1` - `15`, like the row label of a typical spreadsheet. 0-indexed `0` - `14` is acceptable.
3. Orientation - H=Horizontal, V=Vertical - Upper or lower case is OK, or you may choose any other 2 printable ASCII characters.
4. Tiles - `A` - `Z` plus `@` for blank. Upper or lower case is OK, but you only need to support one or the other. You can use a different printable ASCII character for blank if you prefer, but not the space character or a period. The tiles for a move may be a string or a list of characters - e.g., `CAT` or `(C,A,T)`.

Input format may be a tuple, list, separate lines (4 per move) or any other reasonable format. Column + Row may be combined, spreadsheet-style (e.g., `A1`, `O15`), but the orientation and tiles must be separate fields. Column can't be numeric - that is easy for the computer but in the middle of a game we have enough to keep track of, so remembering which # is Row and which # is Column would be too confusing - spreadsheet notation is easy to remember.

### Output

The completed Scrabble board is to be printed in a format similar to [Draw an Empty Scrabble Board](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92055/draw-an-empty-scrabble-board). However, the double/triple squares are not printed and the moves are, obviously, included. Specifically:

- 15x15 matrix
- Unused spaces display as a period `.`
- No leading spaces allowed.
- Trailing spaces allowed.
- One line feed at the end of each row.
- Up to one leading and one trailing line feed permitted.
- Blank tiles are to be output using the same character as input (default `@`).

### Rules

Each move is placed starting with the first tile in the specified location. Each additional tile is to be placed in the **next available** location. In other words, your program must keep track of filled locations and skip them, just like a player placing tiles on the board.

What you **don't need to worry about**:

1. Invalid words - if my daughter and I decided it was OK, you don't have to check it.
2. Invalid locations - these are real moves, so there will of course be enough space to place all the tiles, and you don't have to double-check that a move starts on an empty space (but you can do that if it makes your algorithm shorter since you do have to check for all the other tiles in each move).
3. Proper use of the standard Scrabble set of tiles - e.g., you don't have to check that there are only 2 blanks, 1 Z, etc.

### Examples

[**Sandbox note:** Plan to include a couple of complete games plus a few shorter examples to highlight particular issues]

Input:

```
(G,8,H,CAT)
(G,9,V,OMPUTE)
(F,9,H,RB)
(H,7,H,TIME)
(I,6,V,BE)
```

Output:

```
...............
...............
...............
...............
...............
........B......
.......TIME....
......CAT......
.....ROBE......
......M........
......P........
......U........
......T........
......E........
...............
```

### Scoring

- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: This is a very nice challenge! :-) A few suggestions/answers: yes, allow zero indexed values. I suggest that the input may optionally be numeric for both row and column, but that's up to you. You don't need to mention the next challenge.

Comment: Should you include scrabble game rules too?

Comment: @user202729 I am limiting the rules to those required for the challenge. There are plenty of rules (especially scoring, but also passing/trading letters and a lot of other stuff) that isn't relevant to **this** challenge. If this goes well and I make another challenge for scoring then I will include the relevant rules there. I believe I have enough information here that someone could produce functional code without understanding anything else about Scrabble.

Comment: Suggest to allow other characters than `.` for empty board tiles.

Comment: Are trailing new lines allowed?

Comment: @JayCe ok for both. I need to finish this and turn it into an actual challenge

Comment: It is a really nice challenge indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

## Arithmetic quine

Write a quine.
Well that's not very original challenge so let's spice things up.

**Challenge**

Write a quine which when once or multiple times appended to itself (see Appending)
then performs an arithmetic operation of your choice.
You can implement as many operations from the  as you want (see Scoring, Operations)

**Example**:
Let's say my code were `foobar`. This would return `foobar` because it's a quine.
Now `foobarfoobar` would preform + operation on two input numbers.
`foobarfoobarfoobar` could preform a * operation.

**Note**: which operation you choose for whatever number of appended copies doesn't matter but you have to write it down in your answer.

Example: Your code might be 4 times appended to preform addition, or it might need to be appended 5 times. It doesn't matter as long as you write the full list of the operations you implemented and the number of concatenations needed.

**Operations**

The list of operations you are allowed to implement is:

```
Addition
Subtraction
Multiplication
Integer Division
Integer exponentiation
Integer Factorial
```

**Scoring**

`score = bytes/(n_operations + 1)`

Bytes mean the bytes of the initial un-appended program.

**Appending**

All languages (even if 2D) must be appended by simply concatenating the program two or more times.

Comment: What operations should I add or how should I make this more clear?

Comment: If not duplicate it be good

Comment: I expect that this would be extremely difficult. [Hyperprogramming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92944/61384) is a similar challenge with only addition, multiplication, and exponentiation where its achievability was called into question.

Comment: In my opinion, all languages should be treated equally. Otherwise there would be a lot of disputes (for example: (1) what about Cubix or Hexagony or Wumpus or Quadrefunge, where the layout is not directly rectangular but still >1D? (2) if my language is not 2D can I append horizontally? (3) Can I use a codepage where newline is a different character from `\x10`? )

Comment: Can we read our own source code, or do default loopholes and quine rules apply?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I have the feeling this challenge is easier than that one though. Appending the entire source code allows you to utilize the length, whereas duplicating every character gives all kind of trouble which is harder to overcome/ignore. PS: I've prepared a solution which works with all six operations. Those operations are just examples, right? I could add more if I want to?

Comment: Prepared a solution with nine operations, and will add more later on. :) Looking forward seeing this go live.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen May I know which operations, I'll probably add them to the list

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The list was supposed to be a full list but I don't see why we couldn't expand it, also I'm considering adding a score to each operation, since some are harder to accomplish than others.

Comment: @IQuick143 Well, the ones I have right now are: addition; subtraction; multiplication; integer division; exponentiation; factorial; square; square-root; 1/n. But I could easily add more like regular division; modulo; +1; +2; -1; -2; signum; absolute difference; base-conversion to; base-conversion from; xor; bitwise-and; bitwise-or; negate; halve; double; length; etc. etc. haha ;p So maybe it's good to have a list instead of leaving the choice to everyone. ;) I would personally use add; subtract; divide; int-divide; multiply; exponent; modulo (all requiring two inputs)

Comment: But I'll leave the choice to you. If you want to keep the original six operators that's fine as well. (In which case I would change the sentence to "_The list of operations you are allowed to implement:_")

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was thinking of changing the metric to score = bytes * (operations_language_can_implement - implemented_operations + 1), because some languages might not be able to handle floats for instance, what do you think?

Comment: @JoKing Thanks for the grammar help.

Comment: @IQuick143 Doesn't that give an unfair advantage to those languages? Let's say language A can and has implemented 5 operations in X+5 bytes. And language B can and has implemented 10 operations in X+10 bytes. Although both will get get 1 in the `(operations_language_can_implement - implemented_operations + 1)` part of your scoring, the byte-count of B is X+10, so 5 bytes higher than A's X+5, even though it implemented more operations.. I would keep the scoring as is, and have a select list of operations to implement. If a language can't handle it, it's score would be higher to reflect that.

Comment: And if you want to keep it with integers only, you could perhaps use the following six operation all requiring two inputs: add; subtract; int-divide; multiply; exponent; modulo?

Answer (score 3):

### Find the minimum set of letters to buy

Imagine that you own a board like this:

[image: Black letter board]

which lets you write any message that you want, given that you have the letters for the message. Given that you have a list of messages that you want to switch between, find the minimum number of each letter that you have to order with your board.

As an example, if your messages are `Hello world` and `Hello aliens`, you would need the letters `Helloworldaiens`, as both messages share the `Hello` part and the letter `l` in the second word.

For this challenge, input messages will only consist of letters `a-zA-Z` and space, however note that spaces are not included in the output as you don't need to buy them.

### Input

Input consists of a list of strings, which all match `[a-zA-Z ]+`. There is no limit on the amount of messages that can be provided, or their length.

Output

Output consists of a string of a list of characters, where the letters in the output can be rearranged to create all the input messages, and is of minimal length. The output does not need to be sorted.

Examples

```
['Hello world', 'Hello aliens'] => Hadeeilllnoorsw
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] => abfoorz
['Eat more tacos', 'Drink more tequila'] => DEaaceeiiklmnooqrrsttu
['Golfing is a fun activity', 'Code should be readable'] => CGaabbcdddeeeeffghiiiillnnoorsttuvy
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] => abcdefg
```

This would of course be a `code-golf` challenge

Comment: Hmm ... this is ringing a bell; I think we might have had it before but asking how many of each letter was needed.

Comment: I tried searching for similar questions, but I couldn't find anything. This question would also ask for how many of each letter is needed, but I guess the output format might be different.

Comment: It's [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25625/194), isn't it?

Comment: Darn it, here I thought I had a good challenge going, but I guess the topic was too common. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

## How many times was the function called?

Inspired by [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161713/80010).

Using your language of choice, write a function that takes no argument and returns the number of times it was called.

Specifics:

Your language needs to support something callable (multiple times) that takes no argument (or an empty unused argument) and returns a number or a string representing the number of times it was called, for example 1, 1.0 or "1". Standard I/O applies.

Samples:

```
f() returns 1
f();f() returns 1 2
f();f();f();f() returns 1 2 3 4
```

Note that `f(f(f(f())))` (function composition with itself) is not in the scope of this challenge.

As this is code-golf, the winning solution in any language is the one that uses the fewest number of bytes in this language.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)

Comment: My first question ever - interested to know if is this too trivial or a duplicate. I am aware that a function-oriented challenge restricts the number of languages sadly. related but not a dupe of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11969/80010)

Comment: Can we use a program instead of a function?

Comment: @user202729 I am just not sure how to state it with a program...

Comment: Make the program take no input and output number of times it's called. (require file I/O or something)

Comment: I'm left feeling like I have seen a question for a function which gives a different output each time it is run but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk [maybe this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64902/80010) ?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk [or this one maybe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68820/print-1-to-15-using-different-printers)

Comment: How may we store the state between calls? Self-modifying code? File? Global variable?

Comment: So [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11056/incrementing-numbers-over-multiple-sessions?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the one I thought it was a duplicate of

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk thanks i will take a look at this one and related questions.

Answer (score 3):

## Mixed alphanumeric sort

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

Can't decide if you want to sort by letter or by number? Just do both!

Create a program that, given a series of strings composed of the characters `_`, `0-9`, and `a-z`, sorts them and returns them in order.

---

Sorting is done according to the following algorithm:

- A token is any character among `_a-z` or a **contiguous series** of numerals
- The empty string is sorted first
- Single token strings are sorted as follows:

  - `_` is sorted before numbers, and numbers are sorted before letters
  - Numbers are sorted in numeric order, and letters are sorted from A to Z
  - If two numbers have the same value, the shorter one is sorted first
- Multi token strings are sorted according to the first token. If the first token is the same, then use the second, then third, etc.

---

Here is an example of a sorted list. You can use newlines, commas, or whatever else to separate the items, or you can just use a standard array type.

```
_first
5
5x
5y
123
0123
124
ab_
ab5
ab10
abc
abc
abc00b
abc000a
```

---

### Rules

- Input list can contain empty strings, but is always at least 1 element long
- Input and output may be a list, or a string with separator characters of choice
- Output can also be in-place (modifying the input list), as long as the changes are readable from outside the program
- You can choose to process uppercase characters instead of lowercase ones
- Standard loopholes apply
- Lowest byte count wins

---

### Sandbox questions

- Is the description clear enough, or could anything be added to it?
- It turns out this is a near duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108571/filesystem-sort-my-directory-please), but with the addition of a character that must be sorted before numbers, which changes the strategy. Is this different enough to be its own question?

Answer (score 3):

## Diagonalize a Blackbox [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)

***todo: test cases***

***more math explaination?***

***better challenge definition?***

The function \$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(3x_1,x_1+2x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3)\$ is a linear transformation on \$\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3\$. We can prove this, because like all linear transformations, it satisfies:

- \$f(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)+f(y_1,y_2,y_3)\$
- \$f(\alpha x_1,\alpha x_2,\alpha x_3)=\alpha f(x_1,x_2,x_3)\$

Or, more compactly:

- \$f(\alpha x+\beta y) = \alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)\$

All linear transformations like this can be represented by a matrix multiplication, such as:

$$ M = [f(x)] =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
= (x_1,x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3)
$$
One way to find this matrix is by feeding each of the members of the standard basis for \$\mathbb{R}^3\$, which is \$B = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\$, into \$f(x)\$ to get the columns. This can be for any linear transformation and any basis to get a matrix which represents the transformation in that basis.

For *some* linear transformations, there is a basis \$B'\$ in which \$M'\$ is diagonal - this requires that \$M\$ in \$B\$ be diagonalizable which requires it have unique eigenvalues. However, in this challenge all transformations you have to deal with will fulfill these requirements.

Continuing with the same example, we can determine the eigenvalues of \$M\$ by finding solutions to \$|M-\lambda I_3|=0\$, and the eigenvectors by solving \$Mv=\lambda v\$ for each \$\lambda\$:

$$
|M-\lambda I_3| =
 (3-\lambda) \begin{vmatrix}
2 - \lambda & 0 \\
1 & 1 - \lambda 
\end{vmatrix}
= (3-\lambda)(-(2-\lambda)(1-\lambda))\\
(\lambda-3)(-(2-\lambda)(1-\lambda)) = 0 \implies \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 = 3,2,1$$
This gives us a diagonal matrix \$M' = \begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\$ 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3a\\a+2b\\a+b+c\end{pmatrix}\\
\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a\\3b\\3c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a\\a+2b\\a+b+c\end{pmatrix}\implies v_1=(1,1,1)\\
\lambda_2\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2a\\2b\\2c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a\\a+2b\\a+b+c\end{pmatrix}\implies v_2=(0,1,1)\\
\lambda_3\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a\\a+2b\\a+b+c\end{pmatrix}\implies v_3=(0,0,1)
$$
This gives us a basis \$B'=\{(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)\}\$ where the matrix \$M'\$ represents \$f(x)\$.

In this basis, a vector that would be \$(5,6,7)\$ in \$B\$ is instead \$(5,1,1)\$, as shown here:
$$(5,1,1)_{B'} = 5(1,1,1)+1(0,1,1)+1(0,0,1) = (5,6,7)_B$$

This affects the transformation as well:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\
1&2&0\\
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\6\\7
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
15+0+0\\
5+12+0\\
5+6+7
\end{pmatrix}
=(15,17,18)_B\\
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
15+0+0\\
0+2+0\\
0+0+1
\end{pmatrix}
=(15,2,1)_{B'}\\
(15,2,1)_{B'}=15(1,1,1)+2(0,1,1)+1(0,0,1)=(15,17,18)_B
$$

## Caveats

Notice how when we were finding \$v_1\$ above we picked \$(1,1,1)\$ to simplify. Unfortunately \$v_1=(7,7,7)\$, \$v_2=(0,-3,-3)\$ (and infinitely many more) are also valid in this context.
To make every solution uniform, we normalize each of the vectors:

$$
v_1=\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})\\
v_2=\frac{(0,1,1)}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\\
v_3=\frac{(0,0,1)}{\sqrt{1^2}}=(0,0,1)
$$

So we get a basis \$B'=\{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}),(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}),(0,0,1)\}\$, which corresponds to:

$$(5,1,1)_{B'} = 5(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})+1(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+1(0,0,1)\\ = (\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}},1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}})_B$$

Additionally, we also add a restriction so that the first non-zero element of each eigenvector must be positive, flipping the signs of the rest of the vector if it was initially negative.

## The Challenge

Your task is to write a function or program which takes a black-box function or program and either:

1. outputs a function or program which accepts arguments in a special basis \$B'\$ as described above, performs the transformation on them, and returns the result in the standard basis \$B\$
2. outputs the result in \$B\$ directly and takes the secondary arguments in \$B'\$ itself

## Input

You are given a function (via one of the standard IO methods applicable) taking a vector as input and returning another vector *in the same form, as the same data type*.

Alternatively, you can take a program (via the name of an executable in the current working directory, or a process ID) which takes a vector as input through one of the standard input methods for programs, and outputs a vector in a whitespace-separated string.
(The executable can be in a different language, so don't try to read it.)

The input and output vectors for this function or program are in \$\mathbb{R}^n\$ with basis \$B\$.
You are also given a number specifying the size of the lists to be used (\$n\$ in \$\mathbb{R}^n\$).

If you follow the second option you will additionally receive a vector in basis \$B'\$.

## Output

Otherwise, output a function taking a vector as input and returning another vector, where the function you output uses the standard IO methods for your language. Your submission may output this function as a literal function, function pointer, or as source code for such a function in your language. Instead of a function, you may output a whole program as source code or compiled binary, which takes a vector as input and returns another vector via the standard IO methods for your language.

The input and output vectors for this function or program are in \$\mathbb{R}^n\$.
The input vectors have basis \$B'\$, and the output vectors have basis \$B\$.

If you follow the second option then the above statement applies to your submission instead of the output, and you do not need to output a function nor a program but instead the specified vector.

## Criteria

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes for each language, further subdivided by combination of function / program as input / submission / output, wins!

## Test Cases

***todo***

## Notes

While it's a bit math-y, there are multiple interesting routes to go for a solution to this:

- Transform \$B'\to B\$ and pass to the input function or program
- Follow the question closely and apply the transformation via \$M'\$
- More I won't disclose
- Probably more I haven't thought of

Answer (score 3):

## [Making a Mountain out of a Molehill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173370/75524)

Comment: I'm not clear where the molehills start and end. Based on the description I thought they'd just be ``/\`` without any of the surroundings.

Comment: @xnor does the edit clarify it?

Comment: No, I'm still confused. Being flat counts as going down? Also, from the examples I take it that "down" is taken looking towards the mountain? And what if you have two molehills separated by a flat area, are both molehills considered to include that flat area?

Comment: @xnor no, being flat doesn't count as going down. Where did you get that notion?

Answer (score 3):

## Recognize the hardest context-free language

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [grammars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars)

---

A context-free language is a class of strings that can be recognized by a pushdown automaton, or equivalently produced by a BNF grammar.
In her 1973 [paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/0202025), Sheila Greibach showed that there exists in some sense a "maximally complex" context-free language.
In this challenge, your task is to recognize this language.

## The language

The words of the language \$L\$ use the seven characters \$\mathtt{()[]ABC}\$.
You may use any seven printable ASCII characters in their place, but we use these in the explanation and test cases.
A string \$s\$ is in the language if:

1. It can be broken into \$n\$ pieces: \$s = w_1 \mathtt{C} w_2 \mathtt{C} \cdots w_n \mathtt{C}\$ where the \$w_i\$ do not contain \$\mathtt{C}\$s.
2. Each \$w_i\$ has a substring of the form \$\mathtt{B} x_i \mathtt{B}\$ where \$x_i\$ does not contain \$\mathtt{B}\$s.
3. The concatenation \$x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n\$ has the form \$\mathtt{A} b\$, where \$b\$ is a balanced string over \$\mathtt{()[]}\$.

Note that each \$w_i\$ may have several substrings that begin and end with \$\mathtt{B}\$, but we require that the third condition holds for at least one choice of the \$x_i\$.
Also, some of the \$x_i\$ may be empty.

Here is an example of a string in \$L\$ and an explantion for it:

```
]BA[]BA[](BCB[]BA]B()(BC]B][BB]BCB)BAAB))C
           C           C        C        C    Split by C
     BA[](B B[]B            BB   B)B          Find substring surrounded by B in each part
      A[](   []                   )           Their interiors give A + balanced string
```

Here is a BNF grammar for \$L\$: [TODO: verify that this is correct]

```
<L>        ::= <trash> "BB" <trash> "C" <L>
             | <trash> "BA" <balanced> "B" <trash> "C"
<balanced> ::= <skip-c> <balanced>
             | "(" <balanced> ")"
             | "[" <balanced> ")"
             | <balanced> <skip-cs> <balanced> <skip-cs>
<skip-cs>  ::= <skip-c> <skip-cs> | ""
<skip-c>   ::= "B" <trash> "C" <trash> "B"
<trash>    ::= <not-c> <trash> | ""
<not-c>    ::= "A" | "B" | "(" | ")" | "[" | "]"
```

## The task

Your input is a non-empty string over the alphabet of \$L\$.
As stated above, you may use any 7 printable ASCII characters.
Your program/function shall do one of the following:

- Output a truthy value if the input is in \$L\$, and a falsy value if not.
- Output a consistent value if the input is in \$L\$, and a different consistent value if not.

The lowest byte count wins, and other standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

## Test cases

*TODO*

Answer (score 3):

## Number of Unit Squares Intersecting a Circle

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [oeis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KdLe.gif]

(Credit to [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729) for the illustration)

OEIS sequence [A234300](https://oeis.org/A234300) is defined thusly:

- A radius range is either a single real number at which the circle centered at \$(0,0)\$ passes through some lattice point, or an interval between two such consecutive numbers.
- The first radius range is the number \$0\$.
- The \$n\$th term of the sequence is the number of unit squares on the upper right quadrant of the Cartesian grid whose interior contains some segment of the circle of radius \$r\$, where \$r\$ is in the \$n\$th radius range.

This table shows the radius range and corresponding sequence terms for the first 11 terms of the sequence.

```
Range       Term
0           0
(0,1)       1
1           1
(1,√2)      3
√2          2
(√2,2)      3
2           3
(2,√5)      5
√5          3
(√5,√8)     5
√8          4
```

### Input

A positive integer `n` (or nonnegative for zero-indexed).

### Output

Either the \$n\$th term of the sequence, or a list of the first \$n\$ terms. You may index from \$n=0\$ or \$n=1\$.

Comment: I made a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KdLe.gif). /// I still don't get why integral radius is important, that appears to be a special-case rather than a rule.

Comment: @user202729 wow, what did you use to generate it?

Comment: Logo ([source code](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47847943#47847943))

Comment: I would be pedantic and qualify "*on the Cartesian grid*" as "*in the upper-right quadrant of the Cartesian grid*".

Comment: Surprisingly, this doesn't look like a dupe...

Answer (score 3):

## [43 quintillion permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191444/43-quintillion-permutations)

Comment: I think the requirement for 1:1 mapping is a bit much. I think it would be much more reasonable to only require that there is at least one numeric representation for every possible permutation and that every whole number corresponds to exactly one permutation. I can't even begin to wrap my mind around a solution that ensures there are no duplicate states on the way up to 43-whatever quintillion, but I can think of a few that could theoretically encode any permutation, but with duplicates in the mapping.

Comment: More on "every whole number corresponds to exactly one permutation" - the number of permutations of a rubik's cube requires a minimum of 66 bits to represent, so arbitrary-length integers are already a requirement to implement this challenge, therefore it is totally reasonable to need arbitrarily long integers to represent all permutations.

Comment: @Beefster I have been toying with the idea of converting this to a code challenge, where your score is the number of unique permutations you are able to output.

Comment: The issue with that is that it's trivial to cover all the permutations by associating each bit in the binary representation as whether or not to rotate a certain side 1-quarter turn clockwise. The other issue is that it's very difficult to calculate the minimum number needed to represent all permutations for any given algorigthm. I like the idea of making it a code challenge better than code golf, but I can't think of a good criteria either.

Comment: I think with a few minor clarifications this would be a great code golf challenge; I think it'd be great to see a non-golfed example program to show how it can be done. Also, as Beefster pointed out, a 64bit int cannot represent all required numbers, does `you don't have to worry about the practicalities of actually taking in inputs greater than your language can handle` mean I can still use a 64-bit int? Can I use a *signed* 64-bit int (assuming that makes the code shorter for some reason).

Comment: Additionally, what are the restrictions on display? Do I have to use the colors `WGRBOY`? Can I display the cube flipped for some numbers? (`W` center on bottom, `Y` center on top, etc) Can I display it rotated?

Comment: @Shelvacu The idea I'm trying to get across is that due to the potential size of the input, answers don't have to *actually* perform correctly for each and every input, assuming that the reason why they don't perform correctly is because the input is outside whatever limit the language/type has. So if a Javascript answer works perfectly for all inputs between `1` and `2^53-1`, but fails for `2^53` *because* the input is out of bounds for Javascript, that's completely fine. If it failed for `2^53` because the algorithm used breaks after that many inputs, that's not fine.

Comment: @Shelvacu I'll loosen and clarify the output restrictions in the post itself

Answer (score 3):

## Non-overlapping Matrix Sum

Given *k* arrays of length *n*, output the maximum sum possible using one element from each matrix such that no two elements are from the same position. It is guaranteed that k<=n.

## Input

A nonempty list of nonempty arrays of integers.

## Output

An integer that represents the maximum sum.

## Examples

```
Input -> Output
[[1]] -> 1
[[1, 3], [1, 3]] -> 4
[[1, 4, 2], [5, 6, 1]] -> 9
[[-2, -21],[18, 2]] -> 0
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] -> 15
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 3, 2], [6, 2, 7, 1]] -> 16
```

Comment: @lirtosiast I’m not quite sure what that means.

Comment: @lirtosiast Sorry, still don't understand. If ((3,1),(4,1)) and ((5,9)(2,6)) are the arrays, the function should return 13, but it returns 20?

Comment: I understand the challenge now. Test cases would definitely be useful. I would consider changing to a version with 1d vectors instead of matrices, as the matrix structure doesn't seem to add much.

Comment: @lirtosiast Yeah, makes sense. This actually came up when thinking about programming AI for a game, which is why I wrote it as a matrix to start. I'll change it to 1d arrays

Answer (score 3):

## Output Hello, World! ... sometimes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

On PPCG, [we typically do not allow programs to work only part of the time](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/are-theoretically-incorrect-answers-allowed-if-its-near-impossible-to-find-in). That is, all programs must work with 100% probability unless otherwise stated.

This challenge is going to state otherwise. Your program must, with nonzero probability, output this exact string to STDOUT:

```
Hello, World!
```

However, a simple Hello, World! program will not do. Your program must also have nonzero probability to behave in any other way than outputting the above string. This could be printing another string, printing `Hello, World!` surrounded by junk text, outputting `Hello, World!` to STDERR instead of STDOUT, outputting nothing, crashing, etc. Your program may have many different behaviors than printing the desired string.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

### Example program

The following program in JavaScript is a valid submission. It will output `Hello, World!` half the time, and the other half of the time output a float `>= 0.5`.

```javascript
const THRESHOLD = 0.5;
let randomFloat = Math.random();

let output;

if(randomFloat < THRESHOLD) {
    output = "Hello, World!";
}
else {
    output = randomFloat.toString();
}

console.log(output);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xC8IwEIX3/IqzUwoaXJyim0oHRbCCc2hjrZy5kl5dpL89pnaw@LZ7fHz3HuZl2sLXDS8clTaEglzLcMnOuzw7HbawgaVaaYGWwRtX0nOPZDjWR8N3NVYy1eJLUMdNx/Gob3JKr3/CFN4CYkY0epLMItIcruSxnCVa9MJia/@xiU4x5exrVw1/eyGGyYRWIVVy5FMdwgc)

Comment: Good to have a catalog for IMO.

Comment: Should there be a requirement that HW should be outputted with probability > 0.5 or some threshold?

Comment: @user202729 Good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be different than https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/114520/42963 or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66922/42963

Comment: What's to stop me from outputting 13 random characters? There's a nonzero probability of that outputting "Hello, World!"

Comment: @Beefster nothing, is there something wrong with that approach?

Comment: @user202729 I don't see why enforcing a threshold is a good idea.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I'm not sure why they'd be considered the same as this challenge.

Comment: Perhaps the requirement should be made that the desired output should appear more frequently than any other possible output.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That's another way (that way the challenge becomes strictly harder than HW for most languages) // About the threshold - depends on whether you want to avoid solutions that generate a random string.

Answer (score 3):

## Speeding up powers of 2

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Create a function or program that indefinitely prints outs successive powers of 2 separated by newlines. However, the `n`th term of the sequence (`2^n`) must have a delay of `1/n` seconds either before or after it is printed, but please specify this in your answer. If you choose to add the delay before the number is printed, the first number may optionally have a delay before it is printed.

Your program may begin with `1` or `2` as the first printed number, but if you include `1`, it is considered the 0th term, and your delays must be before each print and skip any initial delay (`1/0` as a delay would not work, hence this rule).

Your program should run properly until it either reaches the integer limit of your language, or until `n = 1000` (a 1 ms delay)

Expected output if `1` is included:

```
1 # after, wait 1/1 seconds
2 # after, wait 1/2 seconds
4 # after, wait 1/3 seconds
8 # after, wait 1/4 seconds
16 # after, wait 1/5 seconds
# etc...
```

Expected output if `1` is not included:

```
2 # before/after, wait 1/1 seconds
4 # before/aftert, wait 1/2 seconds
8 # before/after, wait 1/3 seconds
16 # before/after, wait 1/4 seconds
# etc...
```

---

#### Sandbox

- How should I improve the wording?
- What potential ambiguities or language limits are there?
- Is this too similar to a preexisting challenge?

**EDITS**: Clarified that `n` refers to the term number, not the power of 2

Comment: I like the idea, but any language with arbitrary precision integers is disqualified because it's not possible (and it's not a small set of languages, a lot of languages support)..

Comment: @BMO How is this impossible with arbitrary precision integers? Does it make it difficult to calculate the delays or is there some way in which printing some larger numbers make this impossible? Also, should I require that programs theoretically work for integers beyond the limit of the language (with minor modifications to account for this)?

Comment: The delay needs to be \$\frac{1}{n}\$, any system imposes some \$t_{\min}\$ which is required to output anything at all, as \$n\$ gets larger there will be some \$n_0\$ where \$\frac{1}{n_0} < t_{\min}\$ which is not possible. In short: The delay gets arbitrarily small while the work gets arbitrarily large and at some point this becomes infeasible.

Comment: Are we allowed to sleep `1/1` seconds before printing `2` in the first iteration? Or are we allowed to print `1` and sleep `1/2` seconds afterwards in the first iteration?

Comment: @BMO is indeed right that fairly quickly `1/n` will become 0 in loads of languages. Java for example has a maximum precision of 16 decimal digits after the comma for `floats`/`doubles` (it does have `BigDecimals` for higher precision, but let's ignore those for now). The 64th iteration (number `18446744073709551616`) will have a delay of `5.421010862427522e-17` ms, which is basically `0` in programming languages with 16 decimal digit precision.

Comment: I do like the challenge in general, though (and have prepared a solution if it goes live), so +1 from me. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: You would have to either sleep for `1/1` and then print `1` initially, or sleep `1/2` seconds then print `2` initially, i.e. you must include the term associated with the delay. As for the second point, I would consider that to be starting with `1` and having the delay imposed before printing the `nth term, so it is valid.

Comment: @BMO: Should I instead make the sleep duration something like `n^2`, `(2^n)/n`, or another function that could make this interesting? (I want to avoid using simply `n` to make it a bit more interesting). I would change the title of the challenge appropriately, of course.

Comment: Choosing \$n^2\$ or even \$\frac{2^n}{n}\$ changes things massively. I like the idea of having less time for more work, but: 1) You need to set a boundary, st. the mentioned problem will not occur, if a submission chooses the right approach. 2) To make it interesting, I would balance the boundary and function in a way that the last iteration isn't too easy.

Comment: A starting point (using a Unix system): Investigate how many CPU cycles a write syscall takes (let's assume \$1000\$ - I haven't checked though and it will depend a lot on the environment), assume a standard CPU clocked at \$1.5\$GHz, this gives you \$\frac{1000}{10^{9}\text{Hz}}=1\mu\text{s}\$ for a single write. A delay of \$\frac{1}{2^{31}}\$ (maximum power of two for \$\texttt{uint32}\$) is already half of that.

Comment: @BMO: I may have messed up on my specifics, but what I intended was something along the lines of: when printing `2^31`, there should be a delay of `1/31` seconds, not `1/(2^31)`. (n=the term number, not the power of two).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the challenge (I screwed up, not you). Delaying for \$\frac{1}{31}\$ of a second should be easy. You will still need to add a bound though.

Comment: @BMO: Edited for clarity, limit is n=1000 (1 ms delay, should be handled by most languages fine)

Answer (score 3):

### Static Code Analysis Battle!

Your programs will play a friendly game of rock, paper, scissors. There's a catch though; you can not use randomness and the combatants can see each other's source code.

That is, you will write a python program that, when imported, provides a function named `rps`. Given two combatants, say `player1.py` and `player2.py`, the controller will import them, and execute `player1.rps(player2sourceCode)` and `player2.rps(player1sourceCode)`. These should output `R`, `P`, or `S`. The winner is then whoever would win in rock paper scissors with those moves. If one player makes a valid move, and the other does not, that player wins. If both players make an invalid move, it is considered tie. Additionally, taking more than 1 second to move is considered an invalid move.

Here are the rules:

1. Both the action of importing your module and your rps function should be [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). This means for example that you can not do the following:

   1. Use randomness or other non-deterministic code.
   2. Interfere with or receive information from the file system, I/O, peripherals, etc...
   3. Use `time.sleep`.
   4. Alter or access the state of the controller.
   5. Use other functions to do impure actions. For example, you can not call `eval` on the source code of an impure function call. An exception to this is if the only impure thing it does is interact with your program's state (i.e. it is permitted to change variables in your program's namespace). You can, however, call it on pure function call source code.
   6. Anything else that a pure function could not do.
2. Other functions in your source code, however, may be impure.
3. You may assume that the source code passed as an argument to `rps` obeys rule 1. You may not, however, assume that the `rps` in the passed source code is a pure function when you pass *it* source code that does not obey rule 1. Additionally, other functions in the module may be impure.
4. Additionally, going into an infinite loop is perfectly fine, although if it happens when the caller calls your program, your move will be considered invalid. If the opponent calls your program and it causes *them* to go into an infinite loop, however, their move will be considered invalid, and vice versa.

This is [koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth), so the program that defeats the other programs wins! In particular, I will run a match between each program and each other program. The winner will be the [condorcet winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_winner) if one exists. Otherwise, the result will be a tie between the [Schwartz set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_set) members.

Answer (score 3):

## Classic VCS ASCII Adventure

[Moved to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179225/classic-vcs-ascii-adventure).  Thanks everyone for your input.  Happy golfing!

Comment: This seems like a nice challenge! I'm not as experienced as other people around here, but you should publish it to main.

Comment: These question are likely to be asked: Can input be in decimal (some languages don't have "hex"-numbers and in other languages it's most of the time just a different literal but represents the same)? Can input be binary (maybe even as string)? Does "*any character*" include spaces? Is it restricted to printables only? Is returning an array of strings allowed or does it need to be a single newline-separated string?

Comment: Maybe you could add an example with both *x*- and *y*-stretch factors being negative?

Comment: @BMO thank you for your suggestions!  I've updated the description to address your points.

Comment: I've clarified a few things and added some better test cases.  I'll wait to get a few more up-votes before submitting it though.

Comment: Nice challenge! I've already prepared a solution in case it goes to main. Only perhaps slightly confusing part is where you use the byte-format `018H`/`024H` in the circle example at the top, but then the format `0x18`/`0x24` in your test cases. I would change the `018H`/`024H` in that first example to `0x18`/`0x24` as well to remain consistent across the entire challenge description. Apart from that everything is clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

## The Forest Game (KotH, WIP)

### Summary

You have been given a space of land to plant trees in. Unfortunately, due to an administrative mix-up, so have 4 other people. You are in a competition with them to make the most money out of your trees within the next 100 years.

### The map

A 10 by 10 grid, representing the area of land. Each square will be one of the following:

- A number, `0` to `4`, representing a player
- `.`, representing a seed (more later)
- `i`, representing a sapling
- `T`, representing a tree
- `F`, an ongoing fire
- , an empty space

### Actions

Actions, given by your program, are 1 or 2 characters long. The first is the type:

- `.` - plant a seed, costs 1
- `i` - plant a sapling, costs 10
- `F` - start a fire, costs 5
- `m` - move, costs 0
- `w` - work, gains 1 (what you do for easy points/to do nothing)
- `-` - harvest, variable gains (see below)

Anything else as the first character will result in ignored command. The second character is one of `` `^'<>,v. ``, a direction, which refers to the relative location of the square on which to perform the command:

```
` ^ '     NW N NE
<   > --> W     E
, v .     SW S SE
```

For the work command, the second character need not be present, but must be one of the eight if it is. An invalid command is ignored.

### Growing

Seeds become saplings, saplings trees. After 5 rounds (25 turns), a seed becomes a sapling with the probability \$\frac{8 - C}8\$ where \$C\$ is the number of nearby (diagonally or orthogonally adjacent) saplings or trees. Saplings become trees after 7 rounds, with the same probability (\$C\$ here is **only trees**). This is worked out from the top left, going across each row in turn, meaning that each seed/sapling growth may be affected by saplings/trees created *that turn*.

### Value

When harvested, saplings/trees add to your score. Saplings are valued at 15, trees at 20. After every *round*, a tree gains 1 point of value, up to a maximum of 40 points. Seeds cannot be harvested, nor can other players' saplings/trees.

### Fires

Fires spread from the point you set them to all nearby trees and saplings, unless there is a player other than you also nearby. Example:

```
  T          T          T          T        
  i5         i5         F5          5       
TTTTTT --> FFTTTT -->   FTTT -->    TTT
F1 ii       1 ii       1 ii       1 ii      
  i          i          i          i
```

Where `1` is you and `5` is the other player. Each step represents one turn (not one round).

### Tournament

Each game, you start with 15 points, and loose/gain them as described in the 'actions' and 'value' sections. The aim is to be the player with the most points at the end of 100 rounds (500 turns in total). Each game will be played 6 times, and then repeated until one player has won more than any of the others. This collection of 6+ games is a 'match'. Every two days, if there have been new players added, the players will be split up into groups of 5, padded out with simple bots of mine if necessary. The winners of each of these will be split into groups of five and the above process repeated until there is only one group of five, the winner of which is the victor!

### I/O

Your submission should be a Python 3 program, with a method `run` defined in the global scope. This method will be called with the following parameters:

- `map_` - a list of ten lists of single character strings. This will be a deep copy of the map, each string is one of `01234.iTF`, representing that square.
- `round_` - the round number
- `points` - a list of integers, representing the number of points each player has, in order.
- `num` - whereabouts on the `points` list you come, also the number representing you and where you come in the turn order.

It should output the two/one character string mentioned above.

### Controller

**WIP, extremely buggy**

```
'''
Rules
---
map, 20 by 20 squares,
starts empty with randomly placed players
square can be:
' ' - empty
'1' - [0-4], player
'.' - seed
'i' - sapling
'T' - tree
'F' - flames

actions:
'm' - move
'i' - plant sapling
'.' - plant seed
'-' - harvest tree
'F' - start fire
'w' - work (dir optional and ignored)
'?' - other, nothing

each action other than move should be accompanied by
a direction, [<>^v`,'.O] = (W,E,N,S,NW,SW,NE,SE,O)

flames:
 - go out if person nearby other than starter
 - turn every nearby tree/sapling to flames, 33% each
 - go out, leave ' '

costs/bonuses:
'm' - none
'i' - -10
'.' - -1
'-' - +15 for sapling, +20 for tree + turns living max. +40
'F' - -1
'w' - +1
'?' - none

growing:
. > l - (8-nearby [lT])/8 chance, after 5 turns
l > T - (8-nearby [T])/8 chance, after 7 turns
   T+ - +1 value every turn, max. 40

every five turns, tree drops a seed in an empty nearby square
start at 10 points
game end after 100 rounds

I/O
---
'''

import random, os, time, sys


class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, game, creator=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.game = game
        self.creator = creator


class Flame(Item):
    def update(self, around):
        burn = []
        for i in around:
            if str(i) in map(str, range(6)):
                if str(i) != str(self.creator):
                    return
            elif str(i) in 'Ti':
                burn.append(i)
        for i in burn:
            self.game.place(Flame, i.x, i.y, self.creator)
        self.game.place(Empty, self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'F'


class Seed(Item):
    def __init__(self, x, y, game, creator, count=25, _next=None):
        _next = _next or Sapling
        super(Seed, self).__init__(x, y, game, creator)
        self.counter = count
        self.creator = creator
        self.next = _next

    def update(self, around):
        self.counter -= 1
        if self.counter:
            return
        pos = sum(str(x) in 'Ti' for x in around)
        if random.randrange(8) in range(pos):
            self.game.place(Empty, self.x, self.y)
            return
        self.game.place(self.next, self.x, self.y, self.creator)

    def __str__(self):
        return '.'


class Sapling(Seed):
    def __init__(self, x, y, game, creator):
        super(Sapling, self).__init__(x, y, game, creator, 35, Tree)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'i'

    def __int__(self):
        return 15


class Tree(Item):
    def __init__(self, x, y, game, creator):
        super(Tree, self).__init__(x, y, game, creator)
        self.val = 20

    def update(self, around):
        self.val += 1
        if self.val > 40:
            self.val = 40

    def __str__(self):
        return 'T'

    def __int__(self):
        return self.val


class Empty(Item):
    def update(self, around): pass

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name, game):
        self.game = game
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name
        self.around = (None,) * 8
        self.points = 15

    def update(self, around):
        self.around = around

    def command(self, text):
        text = "mv"
        if len(text) != 2:
            if len(text) != 1:
                return
            else:
                self.points += text[0] == 'w'
                return
        dirs = "`^'<p>,v." #p = placeholder
        if text[1] not in dirs:
            return
        ny = self.y + (dirs.index(text[1]) % 3) - 1
        nx = self.x + int(dirs.index(text[1]) / 3) - 1
        if (nx, ny) == (self.x, self.y):
            return
        itm = self.around["`<,^v'>.".index(text[1])]
        if text[0] == 'w':
            self.points += 1
        elif ny < 0 or nx < 0 or not itm:    #remove for wrapping
            return
        if text[0] == 'm':
            if str(itm) == ' ':
                self.game.move(self.x, self.y, nx, ny)
        elif text[0] == 'F' and self.points > 0:
            if str(itm) in 'Ti':  #never!!!
                self.game.place(Flame, nx, ny, self)
                self.points -= 1
        elif text[0] == '.' and self.points > 0:
            if str(itm) == ' ':
                print('.')
                self.game.place(Seed, nx, ny, self)
                self.points -= 1
        elif text[0] == 'l' and self.points > 9:
            if str(itm) == ' ':
                print('l')
                self.game.place(Sapling, nx, ny, self)
                self.points -= 1
        elif text[0] == '-':
            if str(itm) in 'Ti':
                if itm.creator == str(self):  #never!!
                    self.game.place(Empty, nx, ny)
                    self.points += int(itm)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, players, names, size=20):
        self.map = []
        choose = []
        self.names = names
        for x in range(size):
            self.map.append([])
            for y in range(size):
                self.map[-1].append(Empty(x, y, self))
                choose.append((x, y))
        self.players = {}
        random.shuffle(choose)
        for i in range(len(players)):
            pos = choose.pop()
            p = Player(*pos, str(i), self)
            self.players[players[i]] = p
            self.map[pos[0]][pos[1]] = p
        self.round(1)

    def round(self, number):
        for i in self.players:
            self.updatemap()
            self.turn(i, number)
            if not 'idlelib.run' in sys.modules:
                time.sleep(0.04)
                os.system('cls')
                print(' |0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9')
                print('---------------------')
                [print(str(self.map.index(i)) + '|' + ' '.join(str(j) for j in i)) for i in self.map]
        if number != 100:
            self.round(number+1)
        else:
            [print(' '.join(str(j) for j in i)) for i in self.map]
            for i in self.players:
                print(names[i], self.players[i].points, sep=': ')

    def turn(self, player, rn):
        points = []
        n = 0
        for i in self.players:
            if i == player:
                num = n
            points.append(self.players[i].points)
        text = player(map_=[x[:] for x in self.map], num=num, points=points, round_=rn)
        self.players[player].command(text)

    def place(self, item_t, x, y, creator=None):
        try:
            itm = item_t(x, y, self, creator)
            self.map[x][y] = itm
            return itm
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def move(self, ox, oy, x, y):
        try:
            self.map[x][y]
            itm = self.map[ox][oy]
            self.place(Empty, ox, oy)
            self.map[x][y] = itm
            itm.x = x
            itm.y = y
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def updatemap(self):
        for x in range(len(self.map)):
            for y in range(len(self.map[x])):
                around = []
                for rx in (-1, 0, 1):
                    for ry in (-1, 0, 1):
                        if rx or ry:
                            try:
                                around.append(self.map[x+rx][y+ry])
                            except IndexError:
                                around.append('')
                if str(self.map[x][y]).strip():
                    print(' '.join(str(i) for i in around[:3]),
                          ' '.join(str(i) for i in around[3:6]),
                          ' '.join(str(i) for i in around[6:]),
                          str(self.map[x][y]), sep='\n', end='-----')
                self.map[x][y].update(around)


import burnitall, flamingworker, hardworker, plantandwait, seedandreap
allnames = ('Burn It All', 'Flaming Worker',
            'Hard-worker', 'Plant And Wait',
            'Seed And Reap')
allplayers = (burnitall, flamingworker, hardworker, plantandwait, seedandreap)

players = []
names = {}
for i in allplayers:
    players.append(i.run)
    names[i.run] = allnames[allplayers.index(i)]
Game(players, names, 10)
input()
```

### Game results

Nothing yet!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[ai-player](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-player)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

> ### Sandbox
>
> - Any thoughts? Do you like it?
> - All numbers, rules are undecided, tell me what you think I should change.
> - I know the controller has many bugs, I posted it here to show that one *is* being made but it's very much not ready to use.
> - That doesn't mean I don't want bug reports, if you use it and spot one, please tell me.
> - If you don't like Python - tough. It's all I've got on my computer<sup>*1</sup>, and I don't have space for much else.
>
> <sub><sup>*1</sup> I tell a lie, I have got Java, but so much fuss in implementing it for one more language? I'll think about it...</sub>

Comment: I'd recommend cutting the probability aspect of saplings growing into trees and make it a variable growth rate based on neighbors.

Comment: @Beefster Interesting. I'll think about that.

Answer (score 3):

## Ragtag Band of Misfits

#### (Guaging interest)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

*This is a sort of sequel to [Adventurers in the Ruins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183101/adventurers-in-the-ruins), taking place in a 2D dungeon, using a multi-agent team*

---

A group of five adventurers enters a dungeon and wants to get the best loot. There are other parties competing for loot. Each party member has different abilities, health, stamina amounts, and carry capacity. Each has independent knowledge and must exchange information via a speak action.

The dungeon is made of rooms connected on a 2D grid. A room may have 1-4 doors. Some doors may be one-way. Rooms may have treasures, monsters, and traps.

As in the prequel challenge, treasure requires bidding and all actions resolve simultaneously with a specific priority on action types.

## Party members

There are five classes of characters comprising each party

1. Quartermaster

   - 100kg carry capacity, 10 HP, 1000 stamina, 5 power
   - Can heal party members in the same room
2. Ranger

   - 50kg carry capacity, 10 HP, 1000 stamina, 8 power
   - Can see and attack monsters in adjacent rooms that are connected by a door
3. Fighter

   - 50kg carry capacity, 25 HP, 1000 stamina, 8 power
   - Double damage to monsters
4. Thief

   - 30kg carry capacity, 10 HP, 1500 stamina, 5 power
   - Automatically detects booby trapped treasures and can take them without triggering the trap
   - Can steal treasure from enemy adventurers in the same room
   - Can booby trap a treasure, making it appear twice as valuable, but dealing damage to whoever picks it up.
   - Effective bid on treasures is doubled. Wins ties on treasure bids except against other thieves.
5. Wizard

   - 20kg carry capacity, 8 HP, 1500 stamina, 4 power
   - Can communicate telepathically with any single teammate without needing to be in the same room. This is a two-way channel of communication.
   - Can telepathically visit the room a teammate is currently in, seeing its contents and doors and enabling teleportation to that room
   - Can teleport self or ally in same room to any previously visited room or the same room as any ally.
   - Can teleport any ally to the current room
   - Carried treasure does not increase cost for moving between rooms or teleporting
   - Deals half damage to monsters

### Actions available to adventurers of all classes

- Move between rooms
- Exit the dungeon (if in the starting room)
- Speak (can be combined with certain actions)
- Send a message to the wizard
- Pick up a treasure (bidding rules work the same as the first challenge)
- Gift a treasure to another party member in the same room
- Drop a treasure
- Attack a monster
- Attack a rival adventurer in the same room
- Guard (prevent oncoming attacks and theft attempts)
- Wait

#### Communication

Adventurers can communicate by speaking, which will be heard by all teammates in the same room. Speaking requires no stamina and can be combined with movement or gifting, but is limited to be a 20-character string. (Use of emojis for increased message density is fair game)

## Combat

A power must be specified when attacking a monster. This cannot be higher than the adventurer's power rating. That amount of stamina will be expended and the monster will be damaged by that amount. If the monster is still alive after all attacks have resolved, the monster will then deal its damage split among all combatants that attacked that turn, minimum of 1 damage.

If adventurers are outnumbered by monsters in any room, the monsters will attack anyone attempting to pick up treasure for 1 damage each.

Defeating a monster will cause the monster to drop up to 3 treasures (typically more valuable than the others in the room) and the characters who attacked the monster that turn will level up, gaining 1 power.

Attacking a rival adventurer will deal one fifth of the damage normally dealt to monsters, but will not result in a counterattack. Attacking an adventurer who either guards or moves into another room will result in a miss. It is possible for adventurers to kill each other on the same turn since attacks resolve simultaneously.

## Coding

You will write a bot for each party member. They may not share data (other than constants and libraries).

Answer (score 3):

## Battle of Wits (Where is the Poison?)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

The battle of wits is a [well-known scene](http://wiki.c2.com/?BattleOfWits) from the Princess Bride.

Two bots will face off in a battle of wits: one poisons a wine goblet and the other chooses which to drink from (the other player drinks from the other goblet). Whoever drinks the poison loses. This will be repeated until one bot wins 20 rounds, with who poisons the goblet being randomized each time. Each match, you will be able to see the entire history of which goblet was chosen and you will also have access to the other player's decision function ([Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173065/prisoners-dilemma-with-access-to-opponent)). All submissions will be evaluated in a round-robin tournament, with ties being broken by who has the fewest losses across all games. Further ties will be resolved by who has the fewest losses to the contesting opponents. If there is a perfect intransitive relationship among three or more bots, all of them will be considered tied for first place.

---

This is equivalent to the [matching pennies game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pennies) in terms of who wins a round. The poisoner is equivalent to the penny matcher and the chooser is equivalent to the non-matcher.

Comment: How about, to make it more interesting, let the bots read each other's source code?

Comment: @JoKing ooh. That's genius! [Similar to this?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173065/prisoners-dilemma-with-access-to-opponent)

Answer (score 3):

## Output the Visible Spectrum in RGB

Inspired by http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/color/spectra.html

Light with wavelength between ~380 and 780 nanometers is considered to be within the visible spectrum. One can approximate the colors of the visible spectrum in RGB space by linearly interpolating the wavelength at specific ranges. The ranges and corresponding formulae for a wavelength `wl` are given below, assuming each color value is a real between 0 and 1:

- [380-440): `r = (440 - wl) / (440 - 380), g = 0, b = 1`
- [440-490): `r = 0, g = (wl - 440) / (490 - 440), b = 1`
- [490-510): `r = 0, g = 1, b = (510 - wl) / (510 - 490)`
- [510-580): `r = (wl - 510) / (580 - 510), g = 1, b = 0`
- [580-645): `r = 1, g = (645 - wl) / (645 - 580), b = 0`
- [645-780): `r = 1, g = 0, b = 0`

Note that in this system, the interpolation formula is cyclic with the color components, and changes sign with respect to the range maximum or minimum.

### The challenge

Given an integer wavelength between 380 and 780, output the RGB value using the above interpolations.

Output may be a list of floats in [0,1] or integers between [0,255] in the format (r,g,b), or a valid RGB hex code.

This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases

Rounding errors to within 0.01 in float format or to within 1 in integer format are acceptable.

```
wl=400 --> (0.29, 0.0, 0.65) or (73,0,165) or #4900A5
wl=530 --> (0.28, 1.0, 0.0)  or (72,255,0) or #48FF00
wl=640 --> (1.0, 0.07, 0.0)  or (255,19,0) or #FF1300
wl=750 --> (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)   or (255,0,0)  or #FF0000
```

### Bonus

At extreme ranges of the visible spectrum, human perception is not as good. This can be modeled as a loss of intensity by multiplying the RGB values computed above by a factor `f` for specific cutoff points:

- `wl` < 420: `f=0.3+0.7*(wl-380)/(420-380)`
- `wl` > 700: `f=0.3+0.7*(780-wl)/(780-700)`

The total (r,g,b) including the perception factor is therefore `(f*r, f*g, f*b)`

Comment: I changed your post slightly; feel free to revert if you dislike my changes.

Comment: I also want to notify you of the fact that we have [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) enabled, so you could TeX your equations.

Answer (score 3):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation)

## Approximating Roots

(If you can think of a better title, then please suggest it!)

One day, when I was bored in maths class, I learned of a neat trick for solving the real cube root of a number!

Let's use the number \$79,507\$ as an example.

First, take digit in the one's place and compare it to this table:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
\text{Extracted Digit} &\text{Resulting Digit} \\
\hline
\text{1} &\text{1} \\
\text{2} &\text{8} \\
\text{3} &\text{7} \\
\text{4} &\text{4} \\
\text{5} &\text{5} \\
\text{6} &\text{6} \\
\text{7} &\text{3} \\
\text{8} &\text{2} \\
\text{9} &\text{9} \\
\text{0} &\text{0} \\
\hline
\end{array}

In this example, the `Resulting Digit` will be \$3\$ since the digit in the one's place is \$7\$.

Next, remove all digits that are less than \$10^3\$:

$$ 79507 → 79 $$

Then, find the largest perfect cube that does not exceed the input:

$$ 64 < 79 $$

\$64=4^3\$, thus the next digit needed is \$4\$.

Finally, multiply the digit found in the previous step by \$10\$ and add the `Resulting Digit` found in the first step:

$$ 10*4+3=43 $$

Thus, the cube root of \$79,507\$ equals \$43\$.

***However***, there a neat quirk about this trick: it doesn't apply to *only* cubed numbers.  In fact, it works with all \$n>1\$ where \$n\bmod2\ne0\$.

The steps mentioned above can be summed up in this generalization for an \$n\$ power:

- Step 1) Take the digit in the one's place in the input.  Compare it to the one's place digit of the \$n\$th powers of \$1\$ to \$10\$, then use the corresponding digit.
- Step 2) Remove all digits of the input less than \$10^n\$.  Compare the resulting number to the perfect powers definied in *Step 1*.  Use the \$n\$th root of the largest perfect power less than said number.
- Step 3) Multiply the number from *Step 2* by 10 then add the number from *Step 1*.  This will be the final result.

## Task

Given two positive integers \$n\$ and \$m\$, return the \$n\$th root of \$m\$.

**Input:**

- Two positive integers \$n\$ and \$m\$.
- \$m\$ is guaranteed to be a perfect \$n\$th power of an integer.
- \$n\$ is guaranteed to be odd and greater than \$2\$.  (This method doesn't work if \$n\$ is even.)

**Output:**

- The \$n\$th root of \$m\$.

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewer bytes, the better!
- [Standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) rules apply.
- The output ***must*** be calculated using the aforementioned method.
- No builtins allowed that already calculate this.  A prime example being TI-BASIC's [x√ command](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/xroot).

Comment: That's a pretty neat trick! I guess I'm not the only one who gets bored in math class. Also, I think you made an error on your test case, it says `10 x 4 + 4` rather than `+ 3`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms yes, I believe so!  Guess my finger slipped on the keyboard

Comment: Is there anything else I should change about this post before I post it on main?  Not sure what to call this challenge tbh

Comment: At the beginning of the question, it states that the method only works on perfect cubes, but it later says that it works on all odd numbers > 2. Other than that I don't see many issues, but I'd leave it here for a day or so just in case.

Comment: Good point!  I think that I should remove that line, as it is invalidated later on, as you said.

Comment: Posting to main!  Let's hope that this challenge fares well.

Comment: "*The output **must** be calculated using the aforementioned method*" falls foul of [Things to avoid: Non-observable program requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor it may not be observable directly, but the source code will be able to indicate whether the method was used or not.

Comment: @Tau, read the answer I linked. It explicitly addresses that point.

Answer (score 3):

## Golf my Ada arrays

### Background

[Ada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)) is a programming language that is not exactly known for its terseness.

However, its array literal syntax can in theory allow for fairly terse array
specifications. Here is a simple EBNF description of the [array literal](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-3-3.html)
syntax (passable to [bottlecaps.de](https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui):

```
array ::= positional_array | named_array
positional_array ::= expression ',' expression (',' expression)*
named_array ::= component_association (',' component_association)*
              | expression (',' expression)* ',' 'others' '=>' expression
component_association ::= discrete_choice_list '=>' expression
discrete_choice_list ::= discrete_choice ('|' discrete_choice)*
discrete_choice ::= expression ('..' expression)?
```

We will limit ourselves to 1-dimensional arrays of integers for simplicity. This
means that we will use only integers for the expression values. Perhaps in
a future challenge we could try something more advanced (like declaring
variables and multidimensional arrays). *You do **not** have to golf the integer
literals*.

### Challenge

The goal of this challenge is to output the shortest byte-count Ada array
literal for a given input array. Note that Ada arrays can start from whatever
index is desired, so you can pick what you wish the starting index to be as long
as each value is sequential. In this example I choose to start at 1, which is
idiomatic for Ada, however you can choose to start at any other integer.

#### Input

Your input will consist of a list of integers, in whatever form is convenient.

#### Output

Your output will be a string of text representing the shortest valid Ada array literal that represents the list of input integers. You may use any starting index you wish on this array, but your choice (whatever it is) must be specified in your answer (the starting index may also be dynamic).

Do not modify the representation of the input integers, keep them in decimal format. This challenge does not cover golfing of integer values.

#### Examples

Here are some examples:

```
Simple: [1, 2, 3] -> (1,2,3)
Range: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,] -> (1..7=>1)
Others: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> (6=>2,others=>1)
Multiple Ranges: [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1] -> (6..10|16..20=>2,others=>1)
Tiny Ranges: [1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1] -> (3|4=>2,others=>1)
Far Range: [[1]*5, [2]*100, [3]*5] -> (1..5=>1,6..105=>2,others=>3)
Alternation: [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2] -> (1|3|5|7|9|11|13|15|17=>1,others=>2)
Big Number: [1234567890,1,1234567890] -> (2=>1,1|3=>1234567890)
Big-ish Number: [1234567,1,1234567] -> (1234567,1,1234567)
```

### Minimum Requirements

- Support at least 100 numbers and inputs of at least 256 numbers in length.
- Produce the correct result for all such inputs (including putting 'others' at
  the end)
- Terminate (preferably on TIO) for each of the above inputs in under a minute.

### Reference Implementation

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xRltb5tG@Du/4uQPtVFtFLdbt8axJeK@WUvaKu32FVFzdtAIWHAsjrT/nj13x8G9glO1GpEcOJ739zviJJ7t85g83qfkFoVJHHzFRxJtPi28dmVd3N3FeRJdpTlWlnMSw1JZBZs8wbs0TwmOPpUJLnESXceHSgL@Qso031fBn/m3ogboZOF5h7LY4qQuMboGOiitHhFc5OGA0SYnUViW8QOsopjdTGAN73GJyjjfY3Sx8lGxQ80iUKO4sxkKAR59K/K6miJyC9h1hSu4w4gxrigSfUrzQ00a0sCcLhU1gTVGaFfnW5IWOXpfZLtGEhCAopx3wvmoxKQuc8S1A1kZskKAAm/uYpB4siH4jqNTkXuQ6cVxztG2yCsS50SAnS8FgbFE1l@0yN/wPs0VUukOCVD6b/wuLSvioyUawx8orkLTq5HMxELP0RwFAX8zvoqBzkLBxlmFe8lp4HkC4nVr9Lm1WONUKSgSfNTtVOJtUSYGS4iELyQuCWj5DgKzukWzFarAgBl2w64k2AIMU1YGLAOcCrjzLv50rbhckgpSRIAaRkzAmhkRaGI4EuADoRl7aESx@lELPo7o6w5Tya6GyY64cUb9hFT5ZhA4T5ARPUOjf0fwq7/m5PzhoHPTDYIewr7NZes4j65xSWGv8A78f5Pub4nht8uiyHCcm46jSI1VLpYcWdiFJhQUVwWcA7TwDLsDt0p4gnQifTTZGmet2rJyDeVw0kk8lcXxpwpuI5SMHB8bZP5uqmirWFfkdLqFAt2V@c9FlZL0H6zXeRDekU2UgJlPdHUwo7ZxhVmYjq9wvodelZopfw9Ri86okqPR1P52zk2g5zX7bcqt70DlqQT4xmsexL00RZa4cA3LSNhtKWfa00puj/0baNFbt2U7B/Z0oF1RopC2Wcbshjk2K4qDITcFvDwFsCmHIboAeMgfVlvkPOXqhv4U8btLsJa1/mhNSqjrhGOm1W0JdgxpifMdvhBXj3DPTuAYCqddnsKsoW1x9MKKpzdjeZ06wWxyfNWz9XpgprZ1blhbhPGML/I4i25wVWdEHpVck9ZPTWTyw9OY9Cfx1JXELtucnsgdBfs0OZrQbmjjQ8ddJp0/kugd4u3fVJO/4qzGES9QdNinPsnx/YlbA819f@CH6CvtB10rUQ39NsN3GKzYAfEyZIsnWbLG6sAStNdFDuBnYAxvjHFu38R0d1FrUMONdsyvRWQgT8AXWm5@qXe79PgT@H@ss8yQQOW9tplsXZcVFGkIHHgMWAD27T3ub9PMjJXgQ1xFjUvRZO3ba3yCt1lcYmteUORI7JHkrZHS85zl0RBIEsZSHU29pB4kibJsR@P@XmN3SXg40ELZ33p4QExlrpChy9VoqBl0JchQHrKPKc4rkas72IbsH6AQz7D/QyF3uzMX1zS6DD4f8ZGFzEmd0RHON6z8RIy2HMveyWaGUiIKCDemYzAYxOaxpWljj31F6on8xFsQNdfYHy8855jVYRjWUwcHo5zLzQ32JJWjsls99vbuQB7orUTkqoAxsyL91c70fSEqWCduT8XkQKox6X6ZNlkxsyxte@TGYLxNy4MEw2zOcpwZoyOoeG1313PCkwfyDRvIGZpjIndVaoitMEnkuYNvQsGekw0MvyeFGliJuVlMFVWnSt9Mz3Fu8CGLt5L2MHPzN23Fl4g9ayS2VAxn@ePUNnmFS6KwmbBhsiHo28dqvf4Ywa/VEVaGOEet9X5vo3W5jo/rSbfjo5zF5ugJ7dPuU8U5koBTwdfXimcTCHlBBnRsktlHELjUZ47uow0KgqvIxNUpSG4rCCEEPd8g5wzbthgt0foJMeN9T7OyBNjTbOwqVt1uoqe0sOr3nQZFK/TK5O6IqgZZZORkPkVnvu/3iGZLCkY86jmWt2w7GM7Q2bxEWGh3IVlQrPUd1EskTj@OtznJcSbPH@iL7nvI4tFrjw@jpqyLvRs1x3zhderSoxrtS1IQlvua7enWMInQc@czVUeFcvfVoxk5nOTAv8K3il@VymdzsPi803lU@hwWvMek@QCmHoAeYfPEvw9JxxWWoiNrA5t1@fG5OgXM2BGvO2TwMSX80EFBu6AW18/Shlu3rsVEkwzEUSYN2rqthYufwIj2Zzt/UQ5Mxmdjaofx67Hr0KStZrdxGW8JuB4iVmnXM/0dELUc0Kh8Q8oQzV@8/OXXV7/9/vpsCP5ShR8CXyvgQ9BvZOgh4LcS8BDsuw52CPR9CzoE@UFADgFuGsABuPbQDOqxawulb2BEPn6ueT6iifyJVopkrcB3FYHTpXf0s/PiEfTx5vzi/1/I9/TS7jz6oMP85OslvTwQTfszlrxwHnpv5m8873H@Hw)

This implementation uses the input as its array, with each character being
a number. Capital letters are special constants for large values. The program
argument is the 'start index' to use.

The "code" section in the TIO link is a correct solution to the problem, while the "header" and "footer" implement the test structure.

Comment: Your syntax doesn't match the examples; although I don't know Ada, I do know VHDL (which uses the same array syntax), and I think allowing `others =>` in a named array (like the examples do, and the syntax doesn't) is correct. As for the challenge more generally, the specification is clear but you're missing a victory condition. [tag:code-golf] is our most common victory condition here because it works well for a wide range of problems; I don't see any reason why it would work badly for this one, and don't think any of the usual alternatives are better.

Comment: Oh, one other suggestion is that having more functionality in the reference implementation than is required in users' answers is confusing. You might want to try explaining more clearly what the linked TIO program does, and explaining it as something like "a tool to try out various inputs, supporting abbreviations for some larger inputs, and seeing what the intended output is".

Comment: One other thing that could improve the question: specify what sort of input the program should take (presumably a list of integers), and what sort of output the program should produce (presumably a string). You don't need to define terms like "list" and "string" precisely; people will use whatever definitions make sense for their language. You should probably say something like "for the purposes of this challenge, numbers in the output should be in decimal; you do not have to golf them", because golfing of the output integers could change their length and thus which array syntax is optimal.

Comment: I've added some clarifications.

Comment: "Do not modify the representation" is a bit unclear: the language that people use might be taking input in a format other than decimal, but in that case we still want decimal in the output. Apart from that, I think everything is fine now (and that particular issue isn't unclear enough to make the question closeable, IMO, although close votes are often hard to predict).

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll adjust that and post it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

## Print some very large numbers

Not sure if this has been done before. Write a program that takes in a scientific format number (as two inputs, a mantissa and an exponent), and outputs a decimal representation of that number (as a string). The trick is that this must go far beyond most languages number limits.

The mantissa will always be within 1 ≤ mantissa ≤ 10 or mantissa = 0.

The exponent will always be a 32-bit signed integer.

Example:

```
1, 100 -> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

3.543235, 200 -> 354323500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

3.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333, 10 -> 33333333333.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

5.3282, -71 -> 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053282

0, 999999 -> 0
```

Comment: Nice challenge, but can we use our language's scientific notation, E.g. some languages don't use the `+`, or use a different minus?

Comment: Maybe even allow taking mantissa and exponent as separate inputs?

Comment: Don't forget to add some example cases with negative exponent and one with an integer mantissa. Oh, and also a 0 case.

Comment: Will input always be in canonical format; 1≤|mantissa|<2 or mantissa=0. Can there be leading and trailing 0s in input? How about in output?

Comment: I like the idea of taking the mantissa and exponent as seperate inputs. Then we can do away with the string parsing part of the challenge and just focus on handling big numbers (by giving the inputs as floating point numbers).

Answer (score 3):

## Do X with Y [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Your task is to create a X made of nested 3x3 lowercase Ys, with `n` levels of nesting.
Here is how a X looks like (this is also the output for n = 0):

```
y y
 y
y y
```

A 0-level nested lowercase Y is just `y`.
To nest a lowercase Y a level further, you arrange 4 copies of it like this:

```
y y
 y
y
```

Here is the output for n = 1:

```
y y   y y
 y     y 
y     y  
   y y
    y
   y
y y   y y
 y     y 
y     y
```

Here is the output for n = 2 (I typed all of this by hand; excuse any mistakes):

```
y y   y y         y y   y y
 y     y           y     y 
y     y           y     y
   y y               y y
    y                 y
   y                 y
y y               y y
 y                 y
y                 y
         y y   y y
          y     y
         y     y
            y y
             y
            y
         y y
          y
         y
y y   y y         y y   y y
 y     y           y     y
y     y           y     y
   y y               y y
    y                 y
   y                 y
y y               y y
 y                 y
y                 y
```

## Input

A non-negative integer `n`. You may choose the levels of nesting to be either 0- or 1- indexed.

## Output

A X made of nested 3x3 lowercase Ys, with `n` levels of nesting, as a string, list of lines as strings, or outputted directly.

### Sandbox stuff

- Is anything missing?
- Is the specification of the X clear enough?

Comment: [heavily related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157664/67312) question. I'm not 100% convinced this is different enough to not be a dupe, but I'd try to get some more feedback before posting/abandoning this.

Comment: I think this would be a duplicate. My experience with porting an answer from yet another 3*3 fractal challenge was that I only needed to make a small change in the code.

Comment: I have no idea if should I post this or not, as this both is +3 and seems to receive feedback as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

## Atomic Handshakes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[network](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network)[connection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)[array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

### Introduction

Here you are. At a party, with two drinks in your hands. Your friend just went to the bathroom and you don't really know anyone else here. And so you wait. Or do you?

There is a century old hypothesis known as [Six Degrees of Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation). The hypothesis states, that any other person in the world is connected to you as *a friend <sup>of a friend <sup>of a friend <sup>etc.</sup></sup></sup>.* It would essentially only take you six handshakes to connect with any other person on this planet. But is there actually any truth in this hypothesis? That's what we're about to find out in this challenge!

A similar question also finds its way into my own field of expertise: chemistry. Hence the title. Chemistry is the study of molecules, and molecules get very complex very fast. All (for the sake of simplicity) atoms in a molecule are connected. For certain types of analysis, one may need to know how many connections (bonds) it takes to get from one atom to another.

### The Challenge

In a set of `N` people, each person has a maximum of `N-1` direct connections. Based on this information, it is your task to deduce for every person what the lowest number of connections is to get to every other person.

People (and atoms too) can have similar names. Therefore, instead of a name, every person will get a unique identifier. To make things easy, the identifier will be a non-negative integer and the integers are all consecutive. How convenient!

#### Input

An array-like object of size `N` which lists the first-degree connections for each person.

#### Output

A two-dimensional, symmetrical array of size `NxN` which shows for each person the shortest distance to every other person.

### Challenge rules

- *All* people are connected: there are no loners or isolated groups in the input
- Circular connections are allowed, but
- Only the shortest connection must be output as more ways lead to Rome

### General rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer using the fewest bytes wins.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/), [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Please include a [Try it Online](https://tio.run/#)-link to demonstrate your code working.
- Please motivate your answer with an explanation of your code

### Examples

As the theory may still be somewhat confusing, I will include a network graph for each example. This should make it a lot easier to understand what we're talking about. Here goes!

#### Example 1

Consider the connected set

```
0---1---2---3
        |   |
        4---5---6
```

For this network, our input array will be

```
[[1]          # Since 0 is connected only to 1
 [0 2]        # Since 1 is connected to 0 and 2
 [1 3 4]      # Since 2 is connected to 1, 3 and 4
 [2 5]        # Et cetera
 [2 5]
 [3 4 6]
 [5]]
```

Which should result in the following output (excluding comments):

```
# Distance from
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                   # To
[[0 1 2 3 3 4 5]   # 0
 [1 0 1 2 2 3 4]   # 1
 [2 1 0 1 1 2 3]   # 2
 [3 2 1 0 2 1 2]   # 3
 [3 2 1 2 0 1 2]   # 4
 [4 3 2 1 1 0 1]   # 5
 [5 4 3 2 2 1 0]]  # 6
```

#### Example 2

Consider the connected set

```
.-------.
|       |
|   0   |
|   |   |
|   1---2---3---.
|   |   |   |   |
'---4---5---6   |
    |           |
    7---8---9---'
```

For this network, our input array will be

```
[[1]          # Since 0 is connected only to 1
 [0 2 4]      # Since 1 is connected to 0, 2 and 4
 [1 3 4 5]    # Since 2 is connected to 1, 3, 4 and 5
 [2 6 9]      # Et cetera
 [1 2 5 7]
 [2 4 6]
 [3 5]
 [4 8]
 [7 9]
 [3 8]]
```

Which should result in the following output (excluding comments):

```
# Distance from
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
                         # To
[[0 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 4]   # 0
 [1 0 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 3]   # 1
 [2 1 0 1 1 1 2 3 3 2]   # 2
 [3 2 1 0 2 2 1 3 2 1]   # 3
 [2 1 1 2 0 1 2 1 2 3]   # 4
 [3 2 1 2 1 0 1 2 3 3]   # 5
 [4 3 2 1 2 1 0 3 3 2]   # 6
 [3 2 3 3 1 2 3 0 1 2]   # 7
 [4 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 0 1]   # 8
 [4 3 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 0]]  # 9
```

#### Example 3

Consider the connected set

```
.---0---.
|   |   |
1---2---3
|   |   |
'---4---'
```

For this network, our input array will be

```
[[1 2 3]      # Since 0 is connected to 1, 2 and 3
 [0 2 4]      # Since 1 is connected to 0, 2 and 4
 [0 1 3 4]    # Et cetera
 [0 2 4]
 [1 2 3]]
```

Which should result in the following output (excluding comments):

```
# Distance from
# 0 1 2 3 4
               # To
[[0 1 1 1 2]   # 0
 [1 0 1 2 1]   # 1
 [1 1 0 1 1]   # 2
 [1 2 1 0 1]   # 3
 [2 1 1 1 0]]  # 4
```

Comment: In short, all pairs shortest path. Single-route shortest path would definitely be closed as a duplicate; I would say there's a significant chance that the consensus will be that this is also a duplicate of one of the questions in [tag:path-finding].

Answer (score 3):

## How long's left? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) [text-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188306/how-longs-left).

Comment: Shouldn't the third test case be `FifTy Nine MiNutes And ForTy Six SeConds`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks, fixed

Comment: @Shaggy the challenge here isn't to calculate the number of syllables: it's to find the first number that has the same number of syllables as the distance from the current time.

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it now. Yeah, I think that's sufficiently different, so; ignore my previous comment!

Comment: Could you please clarify how many syllable each number has? (A list should help.)

Comment: @tsh done, see now.

Answer (score 3):

## Too many spies

You are fighting an extensive network of enemy **spies**. You know that each spy has at least one (sometimes multiple) **fake identities** they like to use. You'd really like to know how many spies you're actually dealing with.

Luckily, your counter-intelligence **agents** are doing their job and can *sometimes* figure out when two fake identities are actually controlled by the same enemy spy.

That is to say:

- Your agents don't always know when two fake identies have the same spy behind them, however
- If an agent tells you two fake identities are controlled by the same spy, you trust they are right.

## Agent messages

Agents send you cryptic messages telling you which identities have the same spy behind them. An example:

You have **2 agents** and **5 fake identities** to deal with.

The first agent sends you a message:

```
Red Red Blue Orange Orange
```

This means they think there are 3 spies:

- the first one (Red) controlls identities 1 and 2
- the second one (Blue) controlls identity 3
- the third one (Orange) controlls identities 4 and 5

The second agent sends you a message:

```
cat dog dog bird fly
```

This means they think there are 4 spies:

- the first one (cat) controlls identitiy 1
- the second one (dog) controlls identities 2 and 3
- the third one (bird) controlls identity 4
- the fourth one (fly) controlls identity 5

Compiling the intel we see:

```
Identities:   id1    id2    id3    id4    id5 
Agent 1:    |--same-spy--|       |--same-spy--|
Agent 2:           |--same-spy--|
Conclusion: |-----same-spy------||--same-spy--|
```

This means there are at most **2 spies**.

## Notes

Identities owned by the same spy do not have to be consecutive, i.e. a message like:

```
dog cat dog
```

is valid.

Also, the same word might be used by two different agents - that does not mean anything, it's just a coincidence, e.g.:

```
Agent 1: Steam Water Ice
Agent 2: Ice Ice Baby
```

Ice is used by both agents - the `Ice` used by the first agent is unrelated to the two occurences of `Ice` used by the second agent.

## Challenge

Compile all your agents' intel and figure out how many enemy spies there really are. (To be more precise, get the lowest upper bound, given the limited information you have.)

The shortest code in bytes wins.

## Input and Output spec

The input is a list of n lines, which represent n messages from agents.
Each line consists of k space-separated tokens, same k for all lines. Tokens are alphanumeric, arbitrary length. Case matters.

The output should be a single number, representing the number of distinct spies, based on your agents' intel.

## Examples

#### Example 1

Input:

```
Angel Devil Angel Joker Thief Thief
Ra Ra Ras Pu Ti N
say sea c c see cee
```

Output:

```
2
```

#### Example 2

Input:

```
Blossom Bubbles Buttercup
Ed Edd Eddy
```

Output:

```
3
```

#### Example 3

Input:

```
Botswana Botswana Botswana
Left Middle Right
```

Output:

```
1
```

#### Example 4

Input:

```
Black White
White Black
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: The core problem of union set is nicely presented, but the input requirements are rather too restrictive. The question will be better received if the input is permitted to be received as an array of arrays or any other reasonable list format. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7853/194

Answer (score 3):

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life)[cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)[hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)

Originally posted on main site, moved here for more suggestions.
Better scoring mechanics required.

## Introduction

I've been browsing all those [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) challenges and was thinking "yeah, they're good, but what if we make GoL one?", so here it goes.

## Challenge

Build starting setting for either Conway's Game of Life or other similar cellular automaton (restricted to ones with binary cell state) which after known amount of generation will include square area containing representation of QR code decodable to string "Hello, world!".

- Cell (non-empty state) is interpreted as black pixel, no cell as white.
- Your automation should take at least one generation until result (no hardcoded results allowed).
- Your automation operates on infinite board.
- Not sure if this option will be useful, but you can specify scaling ratio: single integer, setting side of square encoding single pixel. Pixel's color is color of cell dominating by count in it (you can specify 50/50 edge case resolution in your answer). Obviously, in this case side of output area should be proportional to scaling ratio. *This option doesn't affect scoring.*
- It's not necessary, but nice to provide either link to online demo or `.rle` file.

## Example result

[image]

Decodes to "Hello, world!"

## Scoring

Your score is calculated as

```
score = (initial amount of cells)^2*(number of generations until result) + (number of cells out of output area)*5
```

Lower score is better.

Happy GoLfing!

Comment: I think this challenge is interesting, although I suggest that the scoring criterion be a combination of the number of initially on cells and the number of generations necessary to get to the final output, without counting the number of on cells in the output (otherwise there's an aspect of QR code golf in the challenge as well, which complicates matters more). Also, I don't really understand the 4th bullet point. Finally, you seem to want to allow different binary cellular automata to compete, just like different languages. Is this true?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Why would including amount of cells out of output area be bad? It only counts cells which aren't part of QR code, so it seems acceptable. 4th point may probably need some illustrations to make it easier to get (or just remove that). You got the last part right.

Comment: Oh, I misread the "out of output" part. So you allow extraneous on cells outside of the QR code with a penalty?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I think that is more or less fine to have some cells on field as long as output in specified area is correct by itself.

Comment: Could you clarify what classes of automata are eligible? You've specified only binary (two possible cell states). What neighbourhoods are valid? Only the standard 3 by 3 Moore neighbourhood, or also other size and shape neighbourhoods like Von Neumann neighbourhoods? Must all cells in the neighbourhood contribute equally to the outcome (a totalistic automaton) or can different patterns of the same number of "on" cells give different results?

Comment: Where you choose to draw the line is entirely up to you, but it could have a large effect on the nature of the challenge. For example, if arbitrary size and shape neighbourhoods are allowed, with rulesets based on the arrangement of "on" cells rather than just how many are "on", it may be possible to choose a ruleset that gives the output in a single step (maybe - I haven't thought it through). Whether you see that as a bad thing or an interesting way of solving the challenge will determine how restrictive you choose to be. Personally I'd stop short of allowing quite that much flexibility...

Comment: Is there a standard for QR that avoids all disagreement as to what's a valid code? On further thought, it might be better just to requre a fixed output pattern, like some pixel version of Heelo World, and not have the whole QR layer.

Comment: In particular, following @xnor's comment, does "*decodable to*" mean that errors are allowed as long as they're below the threshold for correction?

Answer (score 3):

## Character Frequency in a String

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188684/character-frequency-in-a-string).

Comment: i dislike the special case of space

Comment: @JoKing If there was no special case for space, a string like `1 a` would look something like `1 1;  1;a 1`. Also, it's for the challenge.

Comment: I'm with @JoKing on this; nothing is added to the challenge by special-casing spaces.

Comment: I'd like to further say that restricting the output this much doesn't seem to add much to this challenge. Why isn't, for example, a list of pairs acceptable? I can't find any justification for your output rules. That's not to say you can't do it, but I have a hard time imagining it will be popular.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161921/42963).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, having since given it a try in JS, I'm pretty sure there's a closer (potential) dupe target than that.

Comment: Having posted this, you should delete the sandbox post.

Answer (score 3):

## Golf [range minimum queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) of a list

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), and [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

**Looks like this post hasn't gotten any problems called out, but also not that much support. If you could leave even a brief comment if you don't like it, that would be much appreciated.**

*(Inspired by the [first problem solved](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1146/lectures/00/Small00.pdf) in Stanford’s advanced data structures course.)*

Despite the academicese-heavy name, the problem we're going to solve is almost unbearably simple.

We have a list of numbers.

```
[31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97]
```

We're going to cut some contiguous snippet out of that list of numbers.

```
[31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97]
    |41, 59, 26, 53|
```

And then we're going to find the minimum of that snippet. In this case, that's quite obviously 26. That's all.

And the obvious solution is pretty fast, too, with `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space in the size of the list:

```
minval = arbitrarily large value
for (i=first snippet index, i<last snippet index, i++)
  if (list[i]<minval) minval = list[i]
```

#### So what's with the [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)?

Where it gets interesting is when you try to see how efficient you can make it when you have a fixed list but a large number of range minimum queries -- snippets to find the minimum of. This version of the problem is useful, for example, if you have a huge time series you want to load only once, but you want to find the minimum of many different subintervals of that time series.

In such a scenario, it would actually be faster in practice to literally precompute all `n**2/2` queries, store it in a table, and then just retrieve data from that table for an `O(1)` time and `O(n**2)` space solution. 
[image: Dynamic programming solution from the Stanford slides]
*^dynamic programming solution taken from the Stanford slides*

And then if you're clever enough, you realize that you only have to store each query with size that's a power of two -- you can just combine those power-of-two minima to sum to an arbitrarily sized query, and achieve the same results with constant time and linearithmic rather than quadratic space.

Interestingly, if you keep optimizing, you can get to an `O(1)` time and `O(n)` space solution using a sort of augmented list known as a Fischer-Heun structure. I'd love to go into the details of the structure here, but explaining how it weaves into Cartesian tree building on fixed-size snippets would make this question about 50 pages long. It's explained in the [Wikipedia page linked in the title (which I've copied here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query), however, along with several faster-than-linear intermediate structures.

(If you can get past a research paywall, [here's](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/090779759) the original Fischer & Heun 2011 paper. And if you’d prefer the much more verbose but much more hand-holdy Stanford lecture style, [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/01/Small01.pdf) are the follow-up slides that goes into this solution, including lots of intermediates.)

---

### The challenge

You can either write a full program or a function that calculates the result of a series of range minimum queries given a fixed list. Scoring is set up such that in general, the shortest and most-efficient-over-lots-of-queries code wins.

**Input:**

A list of integers `xs`, followed by a series of `i, j` pairs denoting the start and end of the snippet, inclusive (so the 26 example above uses indices i=1 and j=4). The list of integers is guaranteed to have at least one integer, and `0 <= i <= j < len(xs)`. This can be taken in any format that works best for your language — for example, one list for `xs` and one list of tuples for the `i, j` pairs; or maybe all the different pairs as a variable number of arguments. For a full program that takes in input from stdin, I’ll fix a format for the input:

```
xs[0] xs[1] xs[2] xs[3] ...
i1 j1
i2 j2
i3 j3
...
```

**Output:**

An ordered collection of the range minima for each `i, j` query, in the same order that they were given. In case an unordered map (such as a Python dictionary) from each `i, j` query to its range minimum works better for your language, that will also be allowed as an output; as long as it's obvious which minimum is related to which query.

Once again, for a full program that prints to stdout or a file, I’ll fix the format to have each range minimum on each newline (trailing newlines permitted).

### Scoring:

Lower score is better; score is determined by

```
at(b)^2+as(b)
```

Where `b` is the byte count of your code, `at` is the asymptotic runtime `Ө(n)` of the algorithm in the size of `xs` interpreted as a function of `n`, and `as` is the asymptotic space usage `Ө(n)` in the size of `xs` interpreted as a function of `n`.( All constant coefficients in such `Ө(n)` expressions must be 1, and only the fastest growing term may be kept in expressions, as is standard.)

Therefore, the above pseudocode solution, which uses `Ө(n)` time and `Ө(1)` space, and is 126 characters, would have a score of `(b => b**2 + 1)(126)=15876+1=15877`. (Of course, the pseudocode isn't really valid since it's missing a construct to deal with multiple queries, and also because it's uncompilable pseudocode...)

### Test cases:

**Input:**

```
31 41 59 26 53 58 97
1 4
0 2
5 6
```

**Output:**

```
26
31
58
```

**Input:**

```
1
0 0
0 0
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
```

**Input:**

```
-4 28 31 -54
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
3 3
```

**Output:**

```
-4
-4
-4
-4
28
28
-54
31
-54
-54
```

## Sandbox Questions:

- Would the asymptotic runtime count as a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10002#10002)?
- is this too long and/or abstruse lol
- I’m not sure how to word the scoring section to narrow down the most obvious, basic O(n) expression — an algorithm that’s Ө(n) is also Ө(n/16384-50000) by definition. Is what I have clear enough? Have I left any loopholes?
- I kind of wanted to encourage people to try to implement Fischer-Heun or one of the more time-efficient intermediates in the slides, without restricting them to one particular algorithm (e.g. challenge: you have to make a Fischer-Heun structure). Does the scoring system make sense for this? Is it fair to have, for example, a Jelly answer using the naive algorithm in 3 bytes (score 10) compete with a Jelly answer using the Fischer-Heun structure in 30 bytes (score 31); but a naive Python answer with score 3000+ compete against with a Python Fischer-Heun with score 300?

Comment: `[tag:tag-name]`

Answer (score 3):

## Irish Snap: Variant Rules

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[cards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cards)

## Introduction

Recently, me and a couple of my friends decided to play some cards, and one of them suggested the game 'Irish Snap', which was the inspiration for this challenge. However, I later learnt that the game has a lot of different rules that work ,some of which are listed  [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapjack#Irish_Snap). The rules that are in this challenge aren't currently listed on that page, hence the name, 'Variant Rules'

## The Challenge

Given an array of 3 cards, output a truthy or falsey value depending on if they make a valid snap in a game of Irish snap.

## Input

The input will be an array of 3 numbers, ranging from 1-13 inclusive, with 11 being jack, 12 being queen and 13 being king. The last number in the array will be the number at the top of the stack of cards.

## Rules

The 4 different criteria for if cards make an Irish snap are a snap:

- The top and middle cards are the same
- The top and middle cards have a difference of one
- The top and bottom cards are the same
- The top and bottom cards have a difference of one

If any of these criteria are met, you must output a truthy value. As well as this, for the two criteria that require the cards to have a difference of one, it 'wraps around', meaning that an ace and a king are considered to have a difference of one, and vice versa.

## Test Cases

```
Input -> Output
1 13 7 -> False
1 4 13 -> True
9 3 6 -> False
8 9 7 -> True
2 6 5 -> True
12 5 11 -> True
10 4 8 -> False
12 13 7 -> False
9 7 10 -> True
7 3 1 -> False
```

Comment: Wikipedia describes a [substantially different game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapjack#Irish_Snap) under the same name. Is there any less ambiguous name for this?

Comment: Although I don't think there is a less ambiguous name for it that I can find, the version I described is a combination of the alternate rules listed below the section you linked: 'conventional snap', 'runs', 'sandwiches' and the last rule I listed is basically a combination of 'runs' and 'sandwiches'. How could I change the name to reflect this?

Comment: Should I change the name to "Ultimate Snap", as that's what Wikipedia says those rules are commonly referred to as?

Comment: I think *runs* as described requires all three cards and in the right order. Maybe "Irish snap: variant rules" would be a suitable title, and the introduction can reference Wikipedia and say that the exact rules we'll be using aren't listed (at time of writing the question).

Comment: Ok, I've added in all of those suggestions

Comment: As our token Irishman, I endorse the keeping of "Irish Snap" in the challenge name!

Comment: Do you think I'll be able to post this now?

Answer (score 3):

## Truth Table Composition

Given 2 or more truth tables, output the "shortest" way to compose the first N-1 tables to form the last (Nth) table.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes/io rules apply.
- Input is a "list" of truth tables

  - A truth table is a "list" of rows that contain the inputs and the corresponding output

    - The input will always be the same length for a given table
    - There must be \$ 2^N \$ rows in a given table, where N is the number of inputs in the table
    - Each row must have distinct input
    - Inputs and outputs must both be "booleany" e.g.:

      - `true`/`false`
      - `1`/`0`
      - truthy/falsey
      - `"Bob"`/`"Sally"`
  - The input can be in any **reasonable** format.

    - Any of the formats shown here are reasonable.
    - Taking the output first (ie for &: `1,1,1;0,0,1;0,1,0;0,0,0`) is reasonable.
    - Input that requires non-trivial logic to convert is not reasonable.
    - When in doubt, ask in the comments.
- Output is a "nested structure"

  - Each level of the nest contains information of the:

    - Truth table that was used
    - The ordered inputs (of this structure)
  - If a node is a leaf (one of the inputs to the final truth table) it must:

    - Be distinguishable from the other nodes
    - Contain the index of the input to the final table
  - Output format must be **reasonable** *(see details under input)*
- "Shortest" is measured by the number of nodes in the output structure.
- It will always be possible to construct the last table with the first N-1.
- You do not need to handle invalid input.
- This is [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), so the answer with the smallest asymptotic time complexity wins! Answers that do not aim to be efficient are also welcomed.

<sub>*Yes, I'm done with rules now. Sorry.*</sub>

### Test Cases

For these test cases, the output is explained below. **Note that this is not the output format you have to use!**
 - `$N` is the Nnt input to the final table (0-indexed)
 - `N(...)` is the Nnt input table applied to `...` (also 0-indexed)
   - Arguments are comma separated and are in this format.
 - Note that `N()` is different from `$N`; the former is the Nnt truth table applied to nothing (only valid in the case of truth tables `1` and `0`), and the latter is the Nnt input to the final table.

```
Input:
(anything)

1 0 0
0 1 1
0 0 0
1 1 1

Output:
$1 (length 1; leaf; gives the second input)
```

```
Input:
1 0
0 1

1 1 1
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0

1 0 1
1 1 0
0 0 1
0 1 0

Output:
0($1) (length 2; the first table (not) applied to the second input)
```

```
Input:
1 0
0 1

1

0

Output:
0(1()) (length 2; the first table (not) applied to the second table (true))
```

```
Input:
0 1
1 0

1

1 0
0 1

Output:
0($0) (length 2; the first table (not) applied to the first input to the final table)
```

```
Input:
0 1
1 0

1 1 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

1 1 1
0 1 1
1 0 1
0 0 0

1 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
0 0 0

Output:
1(2($0,$1),0(1($0,$1))) (length 8; "(A | B) & !(A & B)")
```

---

## Meta

I think more test cases are needed, but am unsure what to add.

This is my <s>first</s>second challenge, so all feedback is welcome!

Comment: The idea is good, I think. I had trouble understanding at first read though, and didn't understand at all your `$` things. I suppose `$1` is the same as `1()` but I'm not sure. Suggested test case: Input : `(1,0;0,1) ; (1) ; (1,0;0,1)` with Output : `0()` and not `0(1())` or `1(0())`.

Comment: @V.Courtois `$0` is the first input to the final table, `$1`, the second etc. `0(...)` is the first input table, `1(...)` is the second, etc. Any recommendations on a better format?

Comment: @V.Courtois Added your test case, though `0()` is not a valid output as `(1,0;0,1)` takes in 1 input, not zero, it should be `0($0)`

Comment: Do you mean `$0` is the input on the first row of the output table? It got even more foggy... Plus, isn't a truth table's order meaningless? I mean, you even swapped the order of the rows in the last test case. And I just noticed now the `#` notation... Would you mind clarifying it all? Those signs are nowhere defined in the challenge ^^'

Comment: OH ; and by re-reading all the text I saw that your `&` is strange: why does `0&0` get `1`??

Comment: @V.Courtois The "`&`" is not an `&`, it is an `iff`/`not xor`

Comment: Oh my bad then, I didn't know for this one.

Comment: @V.Courtois Tomorrow I’ll revise the test case format

Comment: @V.Courtois I explained & slightly revised the notation; is it clearer now? If you have any suggestions, they would be very welcome.

Comment: Ah yeah, it looks clearer now. The test case of length 8 is really helpful in the process, too, for guys like me that in general read the test cases before reading what is the actual challenge about :) Let's hear other points of view about this challenge, for my part I don't see any problem now.

Comment: You can remove the "Exception: if there are 0 inputs, there must be 1 row." line, \$2^0=1\$.

Comment: For languages that support ND array, a ND array (each dimension has size 2) would be a natural representation of a N-ary truth table.

Comment: In your example is "1 1 1" = "(1, 1) -> 1" or "1 <- (1, 1)"?

Comment: Also: do you know any polynomial time solution to this problem?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer *shame*. I'll fix that.

Comment: @user202729 `(1, 1) -> 1`. No but I haven't looked into that too deeply.

Comment: The challenge appear to be really hard to code, and naive solution (expected of code golf solution) will likely take a long time.

Comment: @user202729 True, but for smaller inputs I don’t think it will be too bad.

Comment: Though maybe I should change the winning criterion

Comment: Yeah, I’ve changed it to fastest algorithm

Answer (score 3):

## Java vs C++

Now posted at [Time to settle this: Java vs C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194923/time-to-settle-this-java-vs-c)

Comment: How vital is the validation to the challenge?

Comment: @UnrelatedString I think it's fairly integral if the story is considered. Gotta inform the user that they're feeding you crap. Also it should add an extra element of challenge.

Comment: @MrRedstoner Validation is generally considered [tedious](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/31625) by the users of this site, rather than challenging. I'd recommend reconsidering - clearly the validation code could make use of the submissions as a subroutine. There are also a couple near dupes [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74648/31625) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78239/31625) but I haven't found a precise dupe. That said, thanks for using the sandbox!

Comment: `getHTTP` would result in... `get_h_t_t_p`? `get_http`? Error? Some other thing?

Comment: @ChasBrown should be `get_h_t_t_p`, I shall add that. @FryAmTheEggman While I considered it part of the story, if those are the standards I figure I'll remove it and say the validation was done by a previous part of code.

Comment: "_If it is neither, output/return a falsey value._" I would change this to something like "_If it is neither, any unspecified behavior is fine (return a falsey value; give an error; try to convert it somehow anyway; etc.)._" As mentioned by _@FryAmTheEggman_, validation is usually considered a distraction of the actual challenge (and can sometimes even double the code of the program/function for those answering), so most challenges assume the given input will always be valid. Apart from that the entire challenge looks fine, so +1 from me. Thanks for using the Sandbox! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Dang it missed that during the edit. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: What should be returned from an input of `a__b` (two underscores)?

Comment: @ValueInk That would be invalid input. *'You may assume all input to be valid'*. Therefore I refer you to the ANSI C standard for undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

## [What's this constructed number's starter?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/whats-this-constructed-numbers-starter)

Comment: The confusing part is how you mix single and multiple digit numbers.

Comment: @Beefster Could you elaborate on how that confuses you, so that I can try to address it?

Comment: "A concatenated number is a number that can be built this way through the use of the multiples of single digit numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 A.K.A an element in one of these 9 sequences" - I can see the pattern in the example, but this is not very friendly to skimming. Maybe explain what is going on the 3 example? The other thing is that this doesn't really feel like it needs to be limited into multiples of 1 digit numbers.

Comment: @Beefster I'll explain through the 3 sequence to make it clearer. It doesn't need to be limited to 1 digit numbers, although that guarantee that no element will ever be in more than 1 sequence, and is just how I decided to write the challenge.

Comment: I think you might try to find another name (or maybe do not name it at all) for "concatenated number" to avoid the possible confusion of concatenating single and multiple digit numbers. The recurrence is a much clear definition of such sequences and I think that should be put at the very beginning of the description.

Comment: "_Is this clear enough? Is it easily understand what a concatenated number is?_" Completely clear imo, although I agree with @Joel: \$10a + b\$ isn't really concatenating, so the title is a bit confusing for multi-digit numbers later on in the sequences. "_Any other tag suggestions?_" `[sequence]` maybe? And `[integer]` perhaps, although probably not; `[number]` would be enough here, and whether you'd use an `[integer]` or `[string]` is up to the user. "_Is this a duplicate?_" Couldn't find anything like it. "_Any further feedback?_" Some (large) test cases would be nice.

Comment: @Joel I've changed the name to constructed numbers, as it should avoid any confusion and still makes it easier to refer to numbers that meet the criteria

Answer (score 3):

## Shortest Persistent Object in 5-Char JS

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

The `` []+=` `` subset of JavaScript is [known to be Turing-complete](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111002/61384). A key part of the construction is obtaining persistent objects whose properties can be set and retrieved in a loop.

Most expressions won't evaluate to constant values. For example, `[] != []` when compared by reference. However, some expressions, such as `[].name`, return the same object every time they are evaluated.

### The Task

The following should hold when `e` is substituted with your submission:

- `(e) instanceof Object` (this  includes functions and arrays)
- `(e) == (e)`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (measured in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 3):

### Cleaning the dishes

In this task, you will be given a bar of soap with a width of 1 or more units, which will be inputted as an integer. You will also be given a plate, which you will have to clean, using the soap as few times as you can. The plate will be inputted as a an array of 2 different characters, one of which is the 'dirty' character, and one of which is the 'clean' character. The plate will be at least 1 character. You will have to output an array with the 'clean' character representing the plate, and a third unique character to represent in what positions the bar of soap was placed. None of these 3 unique characters may be whitespace.

How much the soap cleans:

```
n//2-1 on each side for odd n
n//2-1 on the left side of the soap bar for even n
n//2   on the right side of the soap bar for even n
```

### Input

An integer greater than or equal to 1. A series of 2 unique characters to represent clean portions and dirty portions.
Here, '=' represents a dirty portion, and '-' represents a clean portion. '+' represents where the soap was placed.

**IN : OUT**

```
3 ===- : -+--
32 ================================ : ---------------+----------------
1 ==== : ++++
5 ----- : -----
4 -====- : --+---
3 -====- : --+-+-
7 === : +--
6 - : -
6 -==-===- : ---+----
5 -==--==- : ---+--+-
3 -==--==- : --+--+--
```

### Rules

- There are multiple solutions. Any one of them are acceptable, as long as they use the soap the minimum amount of times possible.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
- The plate may only be non-whitespace characters, and have 2 unique characters.
- The soap may only be one non-whitespace character, unique from the other 2 used in the plate.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.

Posted: [Cleaning the dishes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192885/cleaning-the-dishes)

Comment: If "soap input may only contain the characters '0' through '9', and may be multiple characters", then can it not be passed as an integer argument to a function?

Comment: i already specified rules about soap input in the first paragraph, so i will erase that rule.

Comment: There seem to be multiple possible outputs, e.,g.: `3 =-=-=` could be either `+--+-` or `-+--+`, yes? If that is true, can we output any of them?

Comment: Yes, any output is acceptable, as long as it works, and is the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

### Battleship KotH

This is a pretty rough idea to start but I figured I would drop it in the sandbox so that people can start to think about it and I will remember to do it.

The idea here is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) that combines the game, [battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) with [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening).

The rough idea is that two enemies would face off, each turn irradiating a location in their opponents source code.  Then the opponents source code would be recompiled and then try and attack back.

Some additional thoughts I've had:

- We will likely want to limit the size of the board to a specific rectangular size
- I would like there to be a feedback from shooting your opponent (in the game battleship this is hit/miss) so that you are doing more than just firing randomly.  Perhaps programs might irradiate a single bit (flipping its value) and get back its value before it was irradiated.

Language choice is a bit tough since I would like something multipurpose and flexible but I don't want to have to deal with the security issues that are involved in compiling and running a fully featured programming language.

Comment: [tag:radiation-hardening] tends to work best with deletion. This is going to need a maximum byte count to be fair, otherwise the best strategy is excessive amounts of whitespace and comments. Love the idea though.

Comment: You don't actually have to limit yourself to a specific language on this one. It wouldn't be that hard to use a shell script to run whatever languages are available. One question though: is each program able to read the source code of the other or is each attack supposed to be blind? If you're worried about security, you could run the controller in a docker container or VM.

Answer (score 3):

## [Injection from two strings to one string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193640)

Comment: Do you think that a reasonably number of languages won't implement the following: convert the strings into numbers (e.g. treat each character as a base 128 digit) then give a resulting string of those two numbers joined by some other character? I haven't spent too long thinking about it but that seems very short in most languages. I suppose there are other variants though where you map characters to some subset and then join them.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I imagine the solution used is going to depend on the language: what builtins it has, if it's more high-level or low-level, etc. But there may well end up being a prevalent algorithm.

Comment: Why strings?  Lists of integers, (even restricted to a range) work as well but don't have the complexities that strings do when it comes to printables etc.  I feel like the simpler challenge is going to be the better one.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Don't worry, I've thought of a totally different approach that I think would be shorter for many languages.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Restricting the character set seems to me like a reasonably simple detail, while making it about strings encourages creativity with string operations, converting to string representations, etc. Also, I personally think string input/output is much more appealing to look at and easier to consume than a list of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## Byte-sized Huffman Coding (WIP)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) [text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text)

[Huffman codings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) are a method to compress data with certain frequency properties, usually text. Normally, these operate on bits rather than bytes, but this challenge will instead operate on whole bytes instead. Since you wouldn't get any benefit otherwise, you can represent multiple consecutive characters with a sequence of one or more bytes, for instance `'. '` (a period followed by a space) could be represented by byte 1, `'The'` could be represented with byte 2, and `'Ishmael'` could be represented by a 255 then a 7 (among many other sequence codings).

## Challenge

Create a program that compresses a plain-text version of a work of literature by returning a byte-wise Huffman coding table and a sequence of bytes that represents the text with that table.

### Rules and Assumptions

- You may assume that the text is written in English and uses only printable ASCII characters plus space, newline, and tab.
- It must be a proper Huffman coding; no mapping may be the prefix of another.
- Not all Huffman sequences need to be mapped to a particular character sequence; you could, for instance, not have 7 mapped to anything or not have 255, 39 mapped to something, but have every other 1 and 2 byte sequence mapped to something.
- The returned coding table must be able to encode every possible sequence of valid characters (as per the first assumption above). The simplest way to do this is to make sure that every individual character is mapped to a Huffman byte sequence.
- It can be possible to encode a body of text multiple ways using the returned encoding table. If both `ca` and `at` are mapped to byte sequences, `cat` could be encoded two ways. This is totally fine.
- Case *must* be preserved.
- Runs do not need to be deterministic, i.e. two runs of the same program with the same input could produce different Huffman tables and compressed output.
- Your program must return a result within a reasonable amount of time to be considered a valid solution. (If you want a hard limit, I'll say 5 minutes on a 2GHz Intel dual-core i5 with 16 GB RAM running Windows 10)

### Scoring

Your results will be run against a corpus of (TBD) 12 publicly available literary (and non-fiction) works. For each work of literature, your score will be the size, in bytes, of the compressed text, plus the total length of all text strings mapped to a byte sequence in the Huffman-coding table. Your overall score is the total score across all 12 works.

Lowest score wins.

#### Literature list

- [*The King James Bible*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ErikSchierboom/sentencegenerator/master/samples/the-king-james-bible.txt)
- [*Hamlet* by William Shakespeare](https://gist.github.com/provpup/2fc41686eab7400b796b/raw/b575bd01a58494dfddc1d6429ef0167e709abf9b/hamlet.txt)
- *Dracula* by Bram Stoker
- *Frankenstein* by Mary Shelley
- *On the Origin of Species* by Charles Darwin
- *Moby-Dick* by Herman Melville
- *Little Women* by Louisa May Alcott
- *Tom Sawyer* by Mark Twain
- *Pride and Prejudice* by Jane Austen
- *The Hound of the Baskervilles* by Arthur Conan Doyle
- < Something that entered the public domain in 2019 because it was published in 1923 >
- < Something written in the last 20 years willingly released into the public domain or with a Creative Commons license that allows derivative works >

> #### Sandbox
>
> At least one of the last two literary works should preferably be written by a female and/or non-white author to hopefully make writing styles diverse enough to make hard-coded Huffman tables ineffective. Each work should be comparable in length to the other works.
>
> Links to these books (in plain text) would be appreciated. Substitution suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you want to vary writing styles, is there a non-fiction work that only contains the allowed characters?

Comment: @trichoplax The most notable non-fiction book I can think of for that would be "On the Origin of Species" by Charles Darwin. I've also thought about throwing in the King James bible. Maybe I could bump up the total to 12 works. I also probably will drop War and Peace because the plain text version I found was machine converted and has issues.

Comment: Regarding plain text books, have you checked Project Gutenberg? They have plaintext versions of many of their books.

Comment: I have no idea how much sample text is a good amount for this challenge (number of books, length of books) but it's probably worth doing some kind of rough check that there is enough text to give variation between answers (no optimal solution) while still being little enough text that running in a reasonable time is realistic (doesn't require weeks of work before an answer is efficient enough to meet the time restriction). Maybe others can suggest good ways of approximating this?

Comment: @trichoplax so basically you suggest sampling out, say, a few chapters instead of the whole book and then reducing the required runtime? I'm open to that, especially since the word count difference between Hamlet and the Bible is so big. The interesting thing about the Bible is that it has a ton of different authors, so it would almost be better to have the first chapter of each book instead of inserting, say, the entirety of Genesis.

Comment: I couldn't guess at this point whether more text or less text would be better, and I don't have a way of estimating, just wondering if anyone else does.

Comment: I see no problem with 5 minutes as a rough time limit. I'd lean towards a time limit that allows someone to write a quick answer and then improve on it gradually, to encourage more participants. How long that needs to be for the text you settle on I don't know. As long as you're confident an optimal solution can't be found, you could just time a naive approach and then choose a time that doesn't exclude that. Then you can get lots of early answers to get the competition going, but still have open ended improvement over the long term

Comment: Not to say that this isn't an interesting challenge as it is but I do wonder if it wouldn't be *more* interesting without *requiring* that we use Huffman Encoding?

Answer (score 3):

## Code Golf Measurer © 2019

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[hexadecimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexadecimal)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Hexdumps used with `xxd` look something like this:

```
00000000: 666f 6f20 6261 7220 7370 616d 2065 6767  foo bar spam egg
00000010: 730a                                     s.
```

Your task is to convert a hexdump in this form in to the number of bytes used.

### Rules:

- Usual loopholes forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest valid answer in bytes wins.
- You may or may not include the newline at the end of text (`0a`). This means that if the hexdump ends in a newline (`0a`), that input may have it's output reduced by one.
- An empty input must output 0.

### Test cases:

```
00000000: 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 2120 4865  Hello, world! He
00000010: 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 210a            llo, world!.
```

returns 27 or 26

```
00000000: 0a                                       .
```

returns 1 or 0

```
00000000: 6368 616c 6c65 6e67 650a                 challenge.
```

returns 10 or 9

```
00000000: 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 21         Hello, world!
```

returns 13

returns 0

### Sandbox:

- Is this clear?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Other tags?

Comment: Does the extra rule mean that the input can have an optional trailing newline, or that the results in all of your test cases could be reduced by 1? If you mean the former I recommend adding a test case that doesn't end with a newline. If you mean the latter then I recommend explicitly saying the file will end with a newline character. Also I suppose this is a [tag:string] challenge. Thanks again for using the sandbox :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It means that all test cases could be reduced by one. This was intended as a code golf byte counter, and the newline most certainly isn't usually included. I'll clarify this and add another test case to highlight it.

Comment: So: discard all the input except the last line, and parse hex? Or just output the last line and claim that your output is in hex? IMO it would be a more interesting problem with `xxd` input, where the last line is not present.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I were to switch to `xxd`, would that be a valid edit, or would that be too big a change such that I would have to post another challenge?

Comment: I'm sure far more significant edits have been made to sandboxed challenges in the past.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In that case, edited.

Answer (score 3):

## Can Jimmy escape the ghosts?

Posted: [Can Jimmy escape the ghosts?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194974/81663)

Comment: S'all good, no problem

Answer (score 3):

## Golfing with 2s

It is well-known that all positive integers can be represented via a sum of powers of 2. For example, `13=2^3+2^2+2^0`. We can rewrite the 3 and 0, to get `13=2^(2+2/2)+2^2+2^(2-2)`. A shorter representation might be `13=2^2^2-2-2/2`, or a more repetitive one `13=2+2+2+2+2+2+2/2`

#### Challenge

Your task is, given a nonnegative integer as input, output/return a string containing only 2s and elementary operations, which when evaluated will yield that integer. These operations are +, -, *, /, ^, and appropriate parentheses. Use of multiple consecutive 2s (22, 222, etc) is not allowed.

However, the string should tend to be one of the shorter representations of the integer in question. So for the above example with 13, `2^2^2-2-2/2` and `2^2^2-2/2-2` are the shortest representations.

The input can be in any convenient format, but the output must be in the above format, either to a file or STDIO.

#### Scoring

Short code and efficient representation are both prioritized, so the score is the length in bytes *plus* the average length of the returned string for 9, 57, 554, 1894, 25993, 113193, 2998225, and 52748566.

#### Rules

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) not allowed

[Standard input/output forms](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply

Some degree of brute forcing *is* allowed, but the program must be able to handle each of the test cases in under a minute each.

#### Example outputs

```
0            2-2
1            2/2
2            2
3            2+2/2
4            2^2
5            2^2+2/2
6            2^2+2
7            2^2+2+2/2
8            2*2*2
9            2*2*2+2/2
10           2*2*2+2
57           2^(2^2+2)-2^2-2-2/2
554          2*2^(2*2*2)+2*2^2^2+2*2*2+2
1894         2*2^(2*2*2+2)-(2^2^2-2)*(2*2*2+2+2/2)
25993        (2*2^(2*2*2+2)-2*2^(2*2*2)-2^2-2-2/2)*(2^2^2+2/2)
113193       2*2^2^2^2-(2^(2*2*2+2)-2^(2^2+2)-2^2^2-2-2/2)*(2^2^2+2+2/2)
2998225      (2*2^2^2^2-(2^(2*2*2+2)-2*2*2-2-2/2)*(2*2*2+2+2/2))*(2^2^2+2*2*2+2/2)
52748566     (2*2^(2^2^2+2^2)-2^2^2^2-2*2^(2*2*2+2)-2*2^(2*2*2)-2^(2*2*2)-2*2*2-2/2)*(2^2^2-2-2/2)*2
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be optimal. It should tend to be optimal but you can trade it out for a much shorter program if it helps.

Comment: It might be a good idea to clarify length - do you mean the actual string length or the number of operations and 2s used?

Comment: Added clarification for both. To Fry, I mean the string length, but I'm not entirely sure what the difference is.

Comment: Can we use the numbers ```22```, ```222```, etc. in the output?

Comment: No. Will add clarification for that as well.

Comment: Can we submit a function that takes a value and returns a string? Typically you should try and avoid restricting input and output, and just rely on the [community standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: _in reasonable time_ I know this is hard to specify, but as it stands it is too broad: what is meant by "reasonable time"? Some previous challenges say things like "it should run within a minute on a modern computer for inputs less than..."

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure how to specify it further. I only really added it because when I showed this challenge to my friend, they wrote a brute-force that goes through every string with those 8 characters and finds the shortest one, and it would take a few minutes for inputs > 30. Does being able to run each of the test cases in under a minute sound good?

Comment: That's the usual tactic, though you should probably specify what  computer it is run on, since some will be faster than others. A possible idea could be the answerer has to run the biggest test case to completion, which should eliminate the worst of the brute force scripts

Comment: Giving the integers you'll be testing with might allow people to optimise those specific inputs sneakily - maybe ask for a TryItOnline link and then give every answer a score yourself? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

## Buildings made from cubes

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

[Posted to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198175/buildings-made-from-cubes); thanks for input provided!

Comment: this looks perfect for fastest-code. with fastest-algorithm it's difficult to do complexity analysis on the solutions.

Comment: @ngn thanks, I’ve amended the alternative suggestion

Comment: it may be good to mention explicitly that all blocks must form a single connected component, otherwise 2 separate 1x1x2 pieces would technically satisfy rules 1-4

Comment: Is this basically \$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n polyminoNumber(i)\cdot i^{n-i}\$?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate no it's not, though it is related to the polyomino numbers. [I've posted to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198175/buildings-made-from-cubes) (sorry for not updating Sandbox post), so please see there for two implementations of code.

Answer (score 3):

### Eats, shoots and leaves

As you know, a panda eats shoots and leaves. Your task today is to write a panda in as few bytes as possible.

```
       1
      / \
     7   5
    / \   \
   2   6   9
      / \   \
     3   8   4
```

Here this tree has two branches, `1-7-6` and `1-5-9`. The branch `1-7-6` has a shoot `2` and leaves `3` and `8`, while the branch `1-5-9` has a leaf `4`. After eating the shoots and leaves, your panda should output the following tree:

```
       1
      / \
     7   5
      \   \
       6   9
```

If your panda is a program or function, it must output the tree in the same format that you input it. Alternatively it can be a subroutine that modifies the tree in-place.

If it helps, you can assume that the tree has at least two nodes, and/or that each node has at most two child nodes.

No standard loopholes.

Comment: What is a shoot, and what is a leaf? Is this question asked to remove all leaf nodes (nodes without children) in a tree?

Comment: @tsh For the purposes of the story, a shoot is a node which has no child nodes but whose parent has at least one grandchild node. Otherwise as you notice it has no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

## Bucket and Minimize

[Post here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198406/bucket-and-minimize)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks for the info. updated

Comment: "_`floor(12%5)+1` into `12 mod 5` buckets, and `floor(12%5)` in the rest_". Shouldn't those `floor(12%5)` be `floor(12/5)` based on your \$\left\lfloor\frac{|L|}{N}\right\rfloor+1\$ formula?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen er, yes. keeping things conventional. in my preferred language (k4) `%` is float division. i'll update it to avoid confusion. thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. In most languages I know `%` is modulo and `/` is division. :) I thought maybe `%` was integer-division in your language of choice, making the `floor` obsolete. But your edit is indeed clearer.

Comment: I would recommend cleaning the body of this answer and linking to the actual challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198406/75323

Comment: @RGS cleaned up

Answer (score 3):

## The uniquely solvable sudoku [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## The task

Given a standard `9x9` sudoku board, output a Truthy value if that sudoku admits one and only one solution. Output a Falsy value if the sudoku has a number of solutions other than one. This means 0 solutions and two or more solutions.

## The input

The board can be given in any sensible format. Some come to mind, and I'll exemplify for a `4x4` sudoku.

- a `2D` array with the state of the board, with any placeholder value for non-filled cells (including the digit 0, or no value at all if your language supports it): `[[1,2,#,4],[#,4,1,2],[2,1,4,#],[4,#,2,1]]`
- a string of the digits row by row or column by column, so `"12#4#412214#4#21"` or `"1#24241##14242#1"`

## The output

A Truthy value if the sudoku puzzle has a unique solution, Falsy otherwise.

## Test cases

(To add)

#### Truthy

#### Falsy

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate with the amount of Sudoku-related challenges we have. Closest related challenge I could find is perhaps [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3582/52210).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for your search! I can link this one, but this is still a new challenge, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

## Parse Iota

Iota is a simple programming language, considered the "sister" of the language Jot. More info can be found [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota) Every Iota program consists of either an `i`, or a `*` followed by two Iota programs. In BNF, this is:

```
iota ::= i | *<iota><iota>
```

## Challenge

Your task is to, given any input, output a truthy or falsy value based on whether or not it is a valid Iota program.

- Your program may take input in any form agreed upon by the community [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/). It just has to be able to take input from the user in some form.
- The same rule goes for output. See the post above for valid output methods. Output may be any truthy or falsy value in your language, including integers, strings, arrays, or objects. If it can be converted to a Boolean, it is OK.

## Example I/O

```
Input: i
Output: 1
```

```
Input: hello
Output: 0
```

```
Input: *i*i*ii
Output: 1
```

```
Input: i*i
Output: 0
```

```
Input: ***
Output: 0
```

```
Input: *
Output: 0
```

```
Input: iiiiiiiii
Output: 0;
```

```
Input: i
Output: 1
```

```
Input: *ii
Output: 1
```

Comment: Suggested test cases: ```*```, ```***```, ```iiiiiiiiiii```

Comment: Ok, I added those @79037662

Comment: I don't get how `i*i*i*ii` is produced. If I understand the grammar right, this is equivalent to checking if parens are matched after removing the final `i` that must come at the end, using `*i` as `()`.

Comment: @xnor - sorry, my bad. i fixed that.

Comment: I think that despite the different presentation, this would be similar enough to checking paren matching to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

### Square Deltas [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Given an *strictly* positive integer `n`, output all numbers in the sequence up to the index `n`. For the current test cases of the current challenge numbers are one-indexed. However, other formats are allowed as default.

### Base sequence

We start from this sequence:

```
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...
```

The sequence is described as follows: `1, 2 (xN), 1` repeated arbitary times. There are 2 more `2`'s than the previous 2-set, and the 2-sequence starts at 1. i.e.:

```
1,       2,       1,
1,    2, 2, 2,    1,
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
and so on ...
```

However, our point is not to output this sequence. For every item in this sequence, add the item by that item of that sequence.

### Adding the sequence

Here's an example of adding the sequence. Here, our sequence starts with 0:

```
  The sequence
    |
    v
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 1 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
...

Our generated sequence is therefore

0, 1, 3, 4, ...
```

### Example test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##TVBBboMwELz7FXu0SZoUeqmQ6Csq9YA4uPIirFprYgyhr6drnKD64p2Z9eysx984eHrbNoM99O9ywpuqBfCZEAkavqJUOxEwzoGgXaH3AVawxOINbM81@Zgxv9FkdpzARRsjV9UJkfxx8W5B6Z05E94fcx62TLQOKYmq5v4p6hC/bBw4Ay7aSUvjzFGU8HNkru2EbUpxH6xD@AwzZrcknli1Z2mLonop1fVa/a9PZfdsvEw@PJfLpvwBXGSG99rzMIaPBqriSJQnpTMGSzG1tPWhduqQvwPqn2yWQlXbVr7@AQ) is a sample program outputting the sequence up to the input.

```
3 -> [0, 1, 3]
10 -> [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13]
```

### Sandbox

- Can the challenge be clarified?

Comment: Why is the task asking for infinite output after index n, rather than a standard sequence challenge? A "standard sequence challenge" usually allows several I/O formats in a single challenge, including "input n -> the number at index n", "input n -> first n numbers", "no input -> infinite output of the sequence".

Comment: No, you don't need to make it harder. And even if it *is* too easy, please don't try to fake up the difficulty by enforcing unnatural I/O requirements.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you want to override the default [tag:sequence] IO? Do you actually have a good reason for doing so?

Answer (score 3):

### Pendulum Encoding [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Given an array as an input (which can be any acceptable/convenient format in your language), implement pendulum encoding.

### How do I do that?

The current **iteration index** starts at `0`.

- If the iteration index is even, append the current item onto the output list.
- If the iteration index is odd, prepend the current item onto the output list.

### An example

```
The input is [a b c d e f g].
Note that the letters a-g are atoms, to prevent confusion from the iteration index.
N: the iteration index

N:0 Out:      [a]
N:1 Out:    [b a]
N:2 Out:    [b a c]
N:3 Out:  [d b a c]
N:4 Out:  [d b a c e]
N:5 Out:[f d b a c e]
N:6 Out:[f d b a c e g]
```

The output should be `[f d b a c e g]`.

## Another example

```
The input is [u d l n u e m p].

N:0 Out:        [u]
N:1 Out:      [d u]
N:2 Out:      [d u l]
N:3 Out:    [n d u l]
N:4 Out:    [n d u l u]
N:5 Out:  [e n d u l u]
N:6 Out:  [e n d u l u m]
N:7 Out:[p e n d u l u m]
```

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##lVLNaoQwEL77FHNZMBhl22OXLeToZdmjyxJK6o5LQKONkV767naibbQUSp1LyMz3MzMJ2lqZe4p9aXXnxjHq0NyGemjiq@QgOLwwSJ9BHKJV5fJRzMXcFyOg2IFun96tdhgLxpeUqeOvq66mw0cOFht4hOMR9l59B6Lz6llA@Ah@BXlBksD1Qq45JPDADgHp7ICzxtni3yLE9zLiW2QCToxltiJMtGLSKvaMUI3ShvYSIGHkZTWKv/KS3zjyit8lY/znDn4T5Lpb@AdBya2EuSW5hSA3OyjyIB@5JmT0KqfWpIPRb/RKDnuXlqpHqGzb0B@gZO@ycfwE)'s a sample program doing this encoding.

Take note that the atoms in the list aren't always unique.

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]   -> [f,d,b,a,c,e,g]
[]                -> []
[a]               -> [a]
[a,b,c,d]         -> [d,b,a,c]
[a,b]             -> [b,a]
[a,b,d]           -> [b,a,d]
[a,b,a,c,b,c]     -> [c,c,b,a,a,b]
[a,a,b,b,c,c]     -> [c,b,a,a,b,c]
[u,d,l,n,u,e,m,p] -> [p,e,n,d,u,l,u,m]
```

Comment: I can't see any issues with this challenge apart from the usual "make sure that you specify that output and input can be taken in any reasonable and convenient format".

Comment: The "example" in the first paragraph is confusing.  It seems to be example input, but it deson't have clear context.  If feels very out of place.

Comment: Are the "atoms" unique? If not, you should at least include a test case where they aren't.

Comment: Naming a generic array `a`, then redefining `a` as a generic atom and never referring to the original array is not very helpful in an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

### Join by intersection [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given a list of strings, output these strings joined by their largest intersecting parts. Your output has to be *optimal*. Strings *have* to be joined in the order given.

### What is an intersection anyway?

Suppose you have two strings:

```
"abcbc" "bcbcd"
```

You extract all suffixes of the first string, as well as all prefixes of the second string:

```
["abcbc", "bcbc", "cbc", "bc", "c"]
["bcbcd", "bcbc", "bcb", "bc", "b"]
```

We trunctuate both of these lists to the length of the list of the smaller length (it's an identity in this current case).

Then, we find all items at the same index which are equal to the other item at the same index:

```
["bcbc", "bc"]
["bcbc", "bc"]
```

We return the longest string of the output. Therefore, the intersection is:

```
"bcbc"
```

### How to join two strings by the intersection

To join by the intersection you simply

1. Append the first string without the intersection to the output string
2. Append the intersection to the output string
3. Append the second string without the intersection to the output string

For example, in our example case:

```
"abcbc" "bcbcd"
(The intersection is "bcbc")

Step 1. Out:"a"
Step 2. Out:"abcbc"
Step 3. Out:"abcbcd"
```

### Reducing a join over a list

If you want to reduce a join over a list

```
["abc","bcd","rfh","hal"]
```

You connect them by their longest common substring:

```
abc
 bcd
    rfh
      hal
=========
abcdrfhal
```

Therefore the expected output is `abcdrfhal`.

### Further walkdown

You cannot join two strings if their substring can be found in the middle. For example:

```
["aXc","bXd"]
```

If you try to match them by the middle substring:

```
aXc
bXd
```

You would realize that the other overlapping characters are not equal to each other. That is, `a` is not equal to `b`, and `c` is not equal to `d`. In that case you simply append the string in the join:

```
aXc
   bXd
======
aXcbXd
```

---

Likewise, if either of these strings contain each other, but isn't equal to the other string, you should simply append the string. E.g.

```
["abcd","bc"]
```

would give

```
abcd
    bc
======
abcdbc
```

---

Substrings can overlap past each other. E.g.

```
["abc","bcd","cde"]
```

would result in the following join:

```
abc
 bcd
  cde
=====
abcde
```

which would evidently make the output `abcde`.

---

Strings have to overlap as much as possible. That means, in this example:

```
["abcbc","bcbcd"]
```

This is not okay (even if they do overlap):

```
abcbc
   bcbcd
========
abcbcbcd
```

Instead, this should be done:

```
abcbc
 bcbcd
======
abcbcd
```

---

The join is consecutive based on the consecutive inputs. For example:

```
abcde
  cde
     abcde
==========
abcdeabcde
```

### Test cases

A program is worth a thousand words. [Here](https://tio.run/##jVHBboQgEL3zFRNOkLCb3WsTv6KXvQJinES0gjab/rwdlIjNmrYcRnnz5s2bAYdlaebewlsF3k3tUAutwCgGdGLn9TNlbuu1GYJABXcFGiJ@OfDYC7P@yq0gHWyEBvd879A6sREvKKGqwOzwTeGhorSqAHdUshJJMxPISykMbppDT26uVzAH@o6XftnIqiJX/iF5hm4Yk4zF2fzYTm4RE6hBT3lIuMB9a68p@@lCdC/9Zdqh07alPR6miDR4eoS0XbrJ11EIZXIhJ6LDOAmujeWKG1tTDE1LsdUdlxI@AvZT17NC9d5TehzHRA2B5@2eUUk16ybl/SFOqQ9DRPsotN9Ud6@2dn8YqFfuv1RJSwHPn@1eqMs3) 's a reference implementation that I use to check the test cases.

```
["abc","bcd","rfh","hal"] -> "abcdrfhal"
["mmm","qqq","rrr"] -> "mmmqqqrrr"
["abcbc","bcbcd"] -> "abcbcd"
["aXc","bXd"]    -> "aXcbXd"
["abc","bcd","cde"] -> "abcde"
["abcd","bc"] -> "abcdbc"
["abcde", "cde", "abcde"] -> "abcdeabcde"
```

Comment: How would you join `aXc` and `bXd`? They have the common substring `X` in the middle.

Comment: Can strings overlap past each other like `abc,bcd,cde->abcde`?

Comment: Do strings have to overlap as much as possible, or just overlap any amount? For example, for `abcbc` and `bcbcd`, is either of `abcbcd` or `abcbcbcd` OK?

Comment: Do strings have to be joined in the order given? I feel like the answer is surely "yes", but the text doesn't say outright. Really, I think all these Sandbox questions come from the fact that the task is never actually stated precisely, and doing that would probably head off any further question.

Comment: Along these lines, what happens if one string contains another? Do we do `abcd,bc->abcd`?

Comment: Suggested test case: `abcde`, `cde`, `abcde`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Well, what's the expected output? I thought it was `abcde` in this case.

Comment: I was not completely sure what the output would be. `abcdeabcde` does seem reasonable.

Comment: I still don't actually understand how the task works precisely. A reference implementation isn't a replacement for a specification.

Comment: @xnor I've added back the spec, can you understand it now?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I still wouldn't know what `abcd,bc` would give.

Comment: @xnor Are there any more test cases you don't understand?

Comment: This seems to be related to the shortest superstring problem for two strings, but you don't have to handle the case where one of the strings is a substring of another, and the joining order is fixed. Is that correct? Just informing that the specification spans four pages on my laptop, with default browser font size.

Comment: @a'_' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem#Shortest_common_superstring

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Ah, it's a [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/shortest-common-superstring). Thank you for the mention.

Answer (score 3):

### Sum in 2540 Sums [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [pristine-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pristine-programming) [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard)

<sup>This is my attempt to pair [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).</sup>

You need to write a program that sums all codepoints of the input string.

### Rules

- The input will always be in printable ASCII.
- The sum of the codepoints of your source must be exactly 2540.

  - You are allowed to use your language's own code page to calculate your program's codepoints.
- Null bytes (which don't contribute to your codepoint sum) are banned.
- The program must not work with any consecutive substring removed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score is the length of your source code, the shorter being better.

Comment: You defined the "base score" only to reference that term exactly once.  It seems to be move confusing than helpful.  Wouldn't "The sum of the codepoints of your source must be exactly 2540" be clearer and shorter?

Comment: Although I am neither suggesting nor recommending against, this could also work as [tag:code-bowling] if you either outlaw null bytes or sum up the (codepoints+1).

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter The rules are a lot simpler if it were [tag:code-golf], and we haven't paired codepoint sum with code golf before. Also I need to fullfill a goal to pair [tag:code-bowling] with [tag:code-golf]. [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18766/cgcc-data-analysis-1-tags)  analysis says that there are 11 tags not paired with [tag:code-golf], I'm going to make it 10.

Comment: As far as I know, [pristine-programming] is the tag for programming with the substring removal restriction here. (I think this would work as a [code-bowling] as well as well)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate So which side are you for? Code golf or code bowling?

Comment: Probably code-golf.

Answer (score 3):

## Will this simplified befunge-93 program terminate? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

The challenge today is to solve the halting problem for *simplified befunge-93*.

Simplified befunge-93 has exactly four instructions - `> v < ^ @`. The program is restricted to a 80x24 grid. Each of the commands modifies the instruction pointer (so that, for instance `>` makes the instruction pointer start executing commands to the right), except of the `@` instruction, which terminates the program.

When the instruction pointer reaches the end, it wraps around (imagine the snake game).

You may read input in form of a string or a two-dimensional array using any reasonable device. The output may be either a truthy value if the program terminates, or a falsy value if the program doesn't terminate.

### Example data

```
Input:
>v
^<

Output: Doesn't terminate.
----------------------------------------
Input:
> v
 @
^ <

Output: Doesn't terminate.
----------------------------------------
Input:
v@
[23 newlines]
>v

Output: Terminates.
----------------------------------------
Input:
v @
[23 newlines]
>v

Output: Doesn't terminate.
----------------------------------------
Input:

Output: Doesn't terminate.
```

Comment: Possibly [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99107/solve-the-halting-problem-for-befinge)?

Comment: is the instruction ptr initially at `0 0` and moving to the right?

Comment: yes, I maybe forgot to state that. But it's most probably a dupe right now, so I don't think I should push it forward anymore :P

Answer (score 3):

[Posted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204457/implement-the-zundoko-kiyoshi-function)

Comment: For the sake of completion: can I give my output as a list of strings?

Comment: @Lyxal Seeing as that's a [generally accepted I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/91030), yes.

Answer (score 3):

### [_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205663/is-this-a-half-sort)

Comment: @mathjunkie then the codepoints given are incorrect.

Comment: @Lyxal Why are they incorrect? I wrote a program to generate the codepoints.

Comment: Oh wait. I thought they were in binary.

Comment: As in, you were using the binary representation of each ordinal value.

Comment: @Lyxal No. I was using the decimal expansion of the ord codes. I am going to clarify that.

Comment: I cam see that now. I just assumed those numbers were base 2,rather than base 10

Comment: Seems pretty clear, but would benefit from test cases with odd-length strings. For example, 'rim' (`false`) and 'rum' (`true`) illustrate the 'first half longer' splitting rule. (Truthiness for these two words would be swapped if the rule were second half longer.)

Answer (score 3):

## Complete a sequence using its distances [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Given \$A = (a_1,\dots,a_k)\ k\ge2 \$ a nonrepetitive sequence of positive integers.
Starting from \$i=2\$, while \$a_i\in A:\$

- If \$d=|a_i-a_{i-1}|\$ is not already in \$A\$, append \$d\$ to \$A\$
- Increase \$i\$

**Output** the completed sequence.

### Example

```
In:  16 20 13 3

     16 20 13 3 4
      --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7
         --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10
            --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1
              --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1
                --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1
                  --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1 9
                     --^
     16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1 9 8
                         --^
Out: 16 20 13 3 4 7 10 1 9 8
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: You could define the self-distances completion for a sequence of positive integers instead of a k-permutation. I believe it would be clearer that way. Also, is the input guaranteed to be duplicate-free?

Comment: @Zgarb Yes, you're right, for the purpose of this challenge refer to a sequence would be totally ok, I've copied this def from the [linked challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18995/94346) where since it's fundamental to consider the max in the input sequence, this number in the context of k-permutation of n - containing n - will naturally be n... But that's not a problem, a k permutation is also a sequence of positive integer. And yes, I forgot to require the input to be duplicate-free

Comment: @Zgarb what do you think about the name? Does it make sense? It's a bit too bulky?

Comment: "append d to (the end of) A" could be clearer to programmers than "prolong A with d". Using "the end of" is optional.

Comment: The name could be "Complete a sequence using its distances" if you want to go for maximum clarity.

Answer (score 3):

[Posted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206370/implement-entombeds-lookup-table)

Comment: Just an observation: the table is *almost* antisymmetric reading top-down vs bottom-up. That is, if you split the table in half based on the value of `A`, then the `X` value in any row in the top half of the table is *mostly* the opposite of the `X` value in the same row (reading upwards from the bottom) in the bottom half. Whether that simplifies the problem at all, I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the [kolmogorov-complexity] tag should apply here, and the [number] tag doesn't seem very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

## Bot Duels KOTH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Obligatory blurb adding story fluff. Or, maybe a self-referential paragraph about meta-self-referential blurbs? Or: `<announcer voice>` *Will your bot survive... **The Arena?*** `</announcer voice>`. Yes, I think a good non-self-referential (such as this) short paragraph full of short sentences without run-ons or many, many, many, many commas will suffice.

### Overview

This is a King-of-the-Hill challenge. Bot with the most wins wins. You may submit multiple bots as long as they differ in strategy. Bots will play against every other bot. The bot who is currently playing against every other bot goes first, and goes second when their opponent is playing against every other bot. Bots will face off in an arena with `x` boundaries of `10` and `-10` and `y` boundaries of `10` and `-10`. Bots will either start at `(-5, 0)` or `(5, 0)`. Your goal is to defeat the other bot by reducing it's HP to `0` or less. Bots start with `20+armor modifier` HP and *do not regenerate health*. Your bot defeats the other bots using `weapons`, which have `damage`, `range`, and `cooldown`. Armor has `speed`.

### Submissions

Submissions should be a JS function that takes the following parameters:

- `curr_x` - the current `x` coordinate of your bot
- `curr_y` - the current `y` coordinate of your bot
- `enemy_x` - the current `x` coordinate of your opponent's bot
- `enemy_y` - the current `y` coordinate of your opponent's bot
- `enemy_armor` - the armor that your enemy is wearing
- `storage` - a storage object you can use to store data between function calls

The function should return an array with 3 items (in the following order):

- `desired x` - the `x` coordinate you want to move to
- `desired y` - the `y` coord you want to move to
- `use weapon?` - if `true`, and `desired x` and `desired y` are `Infinity`, then you use your weapon

Submissions should be structured as

**Weapon: *your weapon here***
**Armor: *your armor here***

```
function definition
block
```

Explanation underneath, if any.

### Armor

(currently designing new weapons and armor)
The types of armor available are:

- `Light` - increases HP by `3`, has a speed of `3`
- `Medium` - increases HP by `5`, has a speed of `2`
- `Heavy` - increases HP by `7`, has a speed of `1`

### Weapons

The types of weapons are:

- `Laser` - High-range, high-damage, low ROF. `5` points of damage, `5` rounds to cool down, and a range of `6` units
- `Rifle` - General-purpose weapon. `5` damage, range of `4`, `3` rounds to cool down.
- `Sword` - High-ROF, high-damage spiky thing. `5` points of damage, really low range of `1`, and a rather quick `2` rounds to cool down.

### Turns

On your turn, you can either move or use weapon (or do nothing, if that's what you really want to do).

- If you `move`, you can move a distance (computed using the [Euclidean Distance formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjTyYHNwYfqAhVQRK0KHa3mA60QFjAIegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEuclidean_distance&usg=AOvVaw0kOx-gkTKwme7Y8C9LPjL0)) less-than or equal-to (`<=`) your `armor`'s speed.
- If you choose to `use weapon`, and if the enemy is in range of your weapon, then you deal damage equal to your weapon's damage and the weapon goes into cooldown. A weapon in cooldown can't be used. Weapons can be used after a number of turns equal to their `cooldown` property has passed after being used.
- To do nothing, simply return your current `x` and `y` coordinates, like so: `return [curr_x, curr_y, false]`.

### Rules

- If you try to use a weapon during cooldown, nothing happens and your turn ends
- If you try to use a weapon and your opponent is out of range, nothing happens and your turn ends.
- If you try to move more than your armor's `speed`, nothing happens and your turn ends
- If you try to move out-of-bounds, same thing
- If you move into another bot's space, then the bot with the lowest HP loses and the bot with the highest HP wins, **making this a viable strategy**.
- All standard loopholes (accessing controller, duplicate bots, suicide bots, etc.) are, of course, **disallowed**.

### Examples

**TowerDefense**
**Weapon: Laser**
**Armor: Heavy**

```
function(curr_x, curr_y, enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_armor, storage) {
    let actions = [Infinity, Infinity, true];
    return actions;
}
```

Just sits and shoots, lol. A perfectly viable strategy (and a rather strong one, too, while weapons are still being reworked). Takes the highest-hp armor available because it doesn't need to move at all.

---

### DumbBot

**Weapon: Rifle**
**Armor: Medium**

```
function(curr_x, curr_y, enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_armor, storage) {
      let actions = [curr_x, curr_y, false];
      // if storage is empty
      if (!storage.data) {
        // then write our starting loc
        storage.data = curr_x.toString() + " " + curr_y.toString();
      }

      // if we're starting at x = -5
      if (storage.data.includes("-5")) {
        if (curr_x < 3) {
          // move right
          actions[0] += 2;
          actions[1] = curr_y;
        }
        // otherwise we must be close enough
        else {storage.data = "shoot";}
      }
```

Assumes enemy doesn't move (such as TowerDefense). Moves to the enemy's starting location, then shoots. As such, takes the Medium armor and the Rifle. Kind of a generic all-purpose bot, like the weapons and armor it uses.

### Controller

The controller can be found [here](https://repl.it/@Squrril/KOTH-Controller#index.html). Run all current submissions [here](https://koth-controller--squrril.repl.co/).

Best of luck, and, *may the odds be ever in your favor* (even though this is a 1v1 and not a FFA)

### Sandbox

- Are the rules explained thoroughly? Is anything unclear?
- Is the game (armor, weapons, punishment for breaking rules, etc.) balanced well? Are there any strategies that dominate?
- Would this KOTH be fun?
- Would *you* participate in the competition?
- Any obvious bugs in the (horribly messy) controller code?
- Create a simple submission similar to something that you would actually submit and test it against the example bots. Is the code still working?

Comment: An arena that contains the points (-5, 0) and (5, 0) would be larger than 10x10. Isn't the `heavy` armor creating more health that can be removed in a turn?

Comment: Armor adds health at beginning of game. It’s a one-time buff. And yes, I messed up the field size. It’s 20x20

Comment: If armor is one-time, then the Light armor is strictly better than Medium because both last only for one shot, leading to various weirdness.

Comment: a) How much health does each bot start with? b) Are you sure the arena is supposed to be 20x20? Not 21x21 or 19x19? As it is one of the bots will have to start closer to the edge (and which one it is isn't specified as far as I can tell). c) Is there a reason why some disallowed actions cause an immediate forfeit while others only make the offending bot skip a turn? d) The "Stuff Not Allowed" and "Other viable strategies" are confusing. Namely, under the first one you list a viable strategy, and under the second - something that's disallowed.

Comment: b.2) On further inspection, is this game grid-based or played on a continuous arena? As in, can you move in fractions? In the second case, (b) becomes irrelevant.

Comment: e) What's the mysterious "Distance formula"? Plain old euclidean distance? Taxicab? Chebyshev? f.1) How do you "include [what weapon and armor your bot is using] in your submission"? f.2) More generally, is there a specific submission format? Or will anything human-readable do? g) Are bots allowed to act randomly with the help of `Math.random`, for example? h) Is it really necessary to override [this loophole?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1916/74965)

Comment: i) Have you considered adding more weapon types or modifying the current set? Currently the choice is pretty one-dimensional, since you avoid varying the damage property.

Comment: As for whether this KotH is fun or not - it seems okay, but I think it lacks variety. Addressing (i) would probably help with that. I would definitely give this challenge a try regardless if it hit main (perhaps as a result of me being a JS KotH junkie).

Answer (score 3):

Comment: What's the upper limit of the output string `Y`?

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' Y is a programming language not a string.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `X`.

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' I didn't put an upper limit, but its length is your score so longer means worse score.  Is there some issue I am not seeing that means an upper limit is needed.

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing you know that that takes up more space right?

Comment: Deleting the post? How does it take up more space? It's no change from 10k+ users and it removes an answer for <10k users

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It does increase the size for users above 10k.  You can test it for yourself if you want.  Further comments *also* increase the size.

Answer (score 3):

## The Turing Text Tape

Posted here: [TTT: Turing Text Tape](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211946/ttt-turing-text-tape)

Comment: If you have a reference implementation, please do add it in.

Comment: I already did, there's a link to a python 3 implementation...

Answer (score 3):

## [Implement the Polygamma function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210425/implement-the-polygamma-function)

Comment: Mathematica: `PolyGamma`.

Comment: Looks good, except that I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You say, "Results may differ due to floating point inaccuracies," but how accurate do results have to be? I'd guess, from "the output should show at least 5 decimal places," that you'd like the results to be accurate to at least 5 decimal places? (But I'm not sure that makes sense for large values like m=46, z=5, since floating point values have significant digits, not significant decimal places.)

Comment: @DLosc I'm not the best when it comes to floating point issues, but I don't see any major issues with requiring the first 5 decimal places to be correct

Answer (score 3):

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/208944/shift-tac-toe-code-golf-challenge)

### Shift Tac Toe [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[tic-tac-toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe)

Shift Tac Toe is a game that combines Tic Tac Toe and Connect 4 together. In this game, you start with a 3 by 3 board, and each row is connected to a slider that you can move left and right. At the start, the sliders all start to the very right(this means that you can't move the slider to the right on the first turn). Each slider can hold a total of 5 pieces. Each turn, the player can drop an O or a X in one of the 3 columns of the Tic Tac Toe grid depending on which turn it is, or the player can move one of the sliders one spot to the left or to the right. All pieces fall to the bottom most space that is unoccupied. The pieces can also fall from one slider to another outside the 3 by 3 grid. If a piece is outside the 3 by 3 grid and doesn't fall into the bottom slider, then the piece is taken out. If it does reach the bottom slider, it will stay in play. A notable example of this is shown in the following grid:

```
     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   - O -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
     --- --- --- --- ---
In the grid above, the dashes(-) indicate the part of the sliders that are outside of the 3 by 3 grid and the vertical bars(|) indicate the 3 by 3 grid.
As you can see, this is the starting board except that the middle slider is one spot over to the left, and that there is an O at the very top right. 
What happens in this scenario? There is nothing immediately underneath it, so does it go out of play? 
No. This is because it still falls into the bottom slider, which means that it is still in play.

The final grid is this:
     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   - O -
     --- --- --- --- ---
```

Pieces can also stack outside of the 3 by 3 grid. Players will alternate between O and X, with the O player going first.

### Example game:

```
Start with 3 by 3 grid with sliders all the way to the right:

 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---

The O player places an O in the middle column of the 3 by 3 grid and it falls to the bottom:

 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
|   | O |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---

The X player then places an X in the middle column:

 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   | X |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
|   | O |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---

The O player then pushes the middle row slider one space to the left. 
Notice that after the slider moves, there is nothing under the X anymore, so it falls down. 
Also note that the slider has moved one space to the right as indicated below:

     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    | X | O |   |   -   -
     --- --- --- --- ---

The X player places a X in the rightmost column:

     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    | X | O | X |   -   -
     --- --- --- --- --- 

The O player then moves the bottom slider one spot to the left.
Notice that all the pieces shift one place to the left, and the leftmost X is now out of the playing field:

     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 

The X player places a X in the leftmost column:

     --- --- --- --- ---
    |   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   | X |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 

The O player places an O in the leftmost column:

     --- --- --- --- ---
    | O |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
-   | X |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 

The X player shifts the top slider one place to the left. Notice that the O falls one place down because there is nothing beneath it:

 --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
- O | X |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 

The O player is not very good at this game, so he shifts the middle slider one place to the right. 
This shifts all the pieces in the middle row one place to the right:

 --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   |   |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    | O | X |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 

The X player wins the game by placing a X in the middle column:

 --- --- --- --- ---
-   |   | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
    | O | X |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- ---
- X | O | X |   |   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
```

Your job is to take in a string or array of any length that only consists of 9 unique characters(you choose the characters). Three of the characters will choose which column you place the X or O(depending on whose turn it is), three of them will choose which slider to move right, and the last three will choose which slider to move left. You can assume that the input only has these 9 characters. The output should be a 3 by 3 matrix or some kind of list/string that clearly shows the final position of the grid upon following the instructions of the input. You can assume that all inputs are valid. Each character takes up a turn. Also, if any move results in a winning move(forms 3 in a row in the 3 by 3 grid like regular Tic-Tac-Toe), then ignore the rest of the input. Note that the pieces that form the winning 3 in a row *all* have to be in the 3 by 3 grid. The two example grids below are NOT winning positions:

```
Grid #1:
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   -   -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
|   |   | O | O - O -
 --- --- --- --- ---
This is not a winning move because two of the O's are outside the playing field, despite the fact that it forms a 3 in a row.
Using the character assignment stated below, this grid pattern can be achieved with 99372467643.

Grid #2:
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   |   - O -
 --- --- --- --- ---
|   |   |   | O - X -
 --- --- --- --- --- 
|   |   | O | X - X -
 --- --- --- --- ---
This is not a winning position because two of the O's are outside the playing field.
Using the character assignment below, this grid pattern can be achieved with 939318836537734654
```

In the examples below, `1`, `2`, and `3` mean drop in the leftmost, middle, and rightmost column respectively. `4`, `5`, and `6` mean to move the top, middle, and bottom slider to the right respectively, and `7`, `8`, and `9` mean to move the top, middle, and bottom slider to the left respectively.

### Examples

```
Input will be in the form of a string
Output will be a list of lists, with each sub-list representing a row(I'm Python programmer so this list format might not be compatible with all languages). 
The first, second, and third sub-list correspond to the top, middle, and bottom row of the 3 by 3 grid respectively. 
The output will have 'O' for the O pieces, 'X' for the X pieces, and an empty string for empty spaces.

Input: 123332
Output:
[['','','O'],
 ['','X','X'],
 ['O','X','O']] 

Input: 33387741347
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','','O'],
 ['X','O','X']]

Input: 2283911752
Output:
[['','X',''],
 ['O','X',''],
 ['O','X','']]

Input: 228374739
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','',''],
 ['X','X','X']]

Input: 8873334917349
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','','O'],
 ['X','X','O']]

Input: 799333466
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','',''],
 ['','','']]

Input: 99372467643
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','',''],
 ['','','O']]

Input: 939318836537734654
Output:
[['','',''],
 ['','',''],
 ['','','O']]
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

### My concerns about this challenge:

Are the rules of this game explained enough? Do you understand this game?

Is this a good challenge overall?

Are the examples correct(if you understand the rules)?

Should I put more examples(or if you understand the rules, could you supply me with some)?

What other tags can this challenge fit into?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Generally it's a good idea to leave challenges in the Sandbox for at least a few days to give people time to review. Even more so if you have questions/concerns about your challenge.

Comment: @Dingus The problem is I already posted it so what do I do now?

Comment: Actually I was referring to future challenges. For this one, there are probably two options: 1. Leave it on main, responding to feedback in the comments. 2. Delete the main post, wait a while (maybe a week) for more feedback here, then repost/undelete on main. The choice really depends on how much needs to be done to iron out the kinks.

Comment: *If the moves result in any unpermitted moves, then output any falsey value* challenges usually assume only valid input unless the challenge itself is to determine only if the input is valid or not.

Comment: @Noodle9 Ok so should I take that out?

Comment: Make it one or the other, either assume valid input and output grid. Or determine whether or not input is valid as the challenge.

Comment: @Noodle9 Ok edited.

Answer (score 3):

## Is this Chessboard Reachable?

The goal of this challenge is to determine, given the state of a
chessboard, whether or not that chessboard can actually be reached in
the course of standard play. Of course, doing this in general is a
rather hard problem, so we'll be simplifying the problem to a set of a
few rules which should approximate the "reachability" constraint.

Your input will be a chessboard, specifying what pieces are at what
positions on the 8x8 board. At each position, there can be either
nothing or a piece. If there is a piece, it is either a pawn, bishop,
knight, rook, queen, or king, and it is either white or black. Input
can be taken in any reasonable form. Your output should be truthy or
falsy, indicating whether all of the below rules are satisfied.

For the below rules, I'll be using standard chess notation to refer to
the squares on the board. That is, I'll be referring to squares on the
board by their rank (1-8) and their file (a-h), as such

```
 8........
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2........
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

where the white player starts on ranks 1-2 and the black player starts
on ranks 7-8. Obviously, you don't have to use the same notation, and
if it's easier for you to take the board input flipped or rotated,
that's fine too as long as you specify it in your answer.

For one of the rules, you have to distinguish between white and black
squares on the board. The board is layered with a checkerboard
pattern, so white squares are always immediately surrounded by black
on all four sides, and vice versa. In typical chess, the a1 square is
black, but that doesn't really matter for the below criteria.

### The Rules

In order for a board to be considered reachable, it must satisfy *all*
of the following rules. This is [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), so you don't have
to tell me which rule an unreachable board violated; all I expect of
your output is a "yes" or a "no".

1. White and black each have exactly one king on the board: no more,
   no less.
2. Pawns cannot appear on rank 1 or rank 8.
3. Each player has a maximum of 16 pieces on the board total. These
   pieces must be a subset of the following: 2 bishops, 2 rooks, 2
   knights, 1 queen, 1 king, and 8 wildcards. The "wildcard" pieces
   can be any piece they please (since we assume pawns could have been
   promoted).
4. For either player, if that player has at least two bishops, and
   those two bishops cannot have been promoted from pawns (i.e. they
   must be the "bishops" in rule 3, not the "wildcards"), then that
   player must have at least one bishop on a white square and at least
   one bishop on a black square.
5. All of a player's pawns must be able to reach the square they're
   occupying. More formally, for each player, there must be an
   assignment (an injective function) from the set of that player's
   surviving pawns to the files (a-h) they started on, such that each
   pawn can reach its current position from its starting position with
   only forward and forward-diagonal movements.

### Pawn Movements

Rule 5 may require some elaboration. Suppose a white pawn is on d5. Then it could have come from the following
places (indicated by `X`)

```
 8........
 7........
 6........
 5...♙....
 4..XXX...
 3.XXXXX..
 2XXXXXXX.
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

So it could have started on a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, or g2, but not h2.
There must be an assignment of pawns to starting positions such that
no two pawns started at the same position and every pawn can reach its
current position from where it began. A black pawn follows the same
rules but started on rank 7 and moves down rather than up. So a black
pawn at the same position could have come from b7, c7, d7, e7, or f7,
as follows.

```
 8........
 7.XXXXX..
 6..XXX...
 5...♟....
 4........
 3........
 2........
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

### Notes

- Only the rules above apply. Other complexities of a standard game
  of chess (in particular, castling or en passant) are not part of
  this problem and should not be considered.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.
- Input can be taken in whatever form is most convenient. Output
  follows the usual [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules, so any two distinct
  outputs for truthy/falsy are acceptable.
- This is an oversimplification of the reachability problem in chess.
  As such, an answer which provably enumerates every chessboard and
  tests for membership is not correct.

### Examples

**Reachable chessboards (true):**

```
 8♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh

 8........
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2..♚.....
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh

 8........
 7.....♚..
 6.♛......
 5...♟....
 4........
 3.....♕..
 2........
 1...♔....
  abcdefgh

 8.....♚..
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1....♔...
  abcdefgh

 8.....♚...
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1....♔...
  abcdefgh

 8........
 7.♚......
 6...♕♕♕♕.
 5..♕....♕
 4..♕..♔.♕
 3.......♕
 2........
 1........
  abcdefgh

 8........
 7...♚.♟.♙
 6.♙.♙..♙.
 5.....♘..
 4.♕..♕♘♗♖
 3.....♘♗♖
 2..♕....♖
 1......♔.
  abcdefgh

 8♜..♛♚♜♜♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟..
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh

 8♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙.
 1♖♗♘♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh

 8♛♛♛♛♛♛.♛
 7........
 6......♚.
 5.♝.♝....
 4.....♟..
 3........
 2..♖♖♖.♔.
 1........
  abcdefgh

 8.....♚..
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3.♙♙.....
 2..♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh

 8.....♚..
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3.....♙..
 2...♙♙♙.♙
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh

 8.....♚..
 7........
 6.♟♟♟♟...
 5.♟♟.....
 4........
 3........
 2........
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh
```

**Unreachable chessboards (false):**

(Rule 1: Not enough kings)

```
 8........
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2........
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 1: Too many kings)

```
 8♚♚♚♚♚♚♚♚
 7♚♚♚♚♚♚♚♚
 6♚♚♚♚♚♚♚♚
 5♚♚♚♚♚♚♚♚
 4♚♚♚♚♚♚♚♚
 3........
 2........
 1...♔....
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 2: Bad white pawn placement)

```
 8.....♚..
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2.♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♙...♔...
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 2: Bad black pawn placement)

```
 8.♟...♚..
 7♟.♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1....♔...
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 3: Too many white queens)

```
 8........
 7.♚......
 6...♕♕♕♕.
 5..♕....♕
 4..♕..♔.♕
 3..♕....♕
 2........
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 3: Too many black pieces)

```
 8♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6......♟.
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 3: Too many white pieces)

```
 8........
 7...♚.♙.♙
 6.♙.♙..♙.
 5.....♘..
 4.♕..♕♘♗♖
 3.....♘♗♖
 2..♕....♖
 1......♔.
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 3: Too many black rooks)

```
 8♜..♛♚♜♜♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟.
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 4: White bishops are the same color)

```
 8♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
 7♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3........
 2♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1♖♗♘♕♔♗♘♖
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 4: Black bishops are the same color)

```
 8♛♛♛♛♛♛♛♛
 7........
 6......♚.
 5.♝.♝....
 4.....♟..
 3........
 2..♖♖♖.♔.
 1........
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 5: White pawn placement is impossible)

```
 8.....♚..
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3..♙.....
 2.♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 5: White pawn placement is impossible)

```
 8.....♚..
 7........
 6........
 5........
 4........
 3.....♙.♙
 2...♙♙♙.♙
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh
```

(Rule 5: Black pawn placement is impossible)

```
 8.....♚..
 7.♟♟♟♟...
 6........
 5.♟♟.....
 4.♟♟.....
 3........
 2........
 1.....♔..
  abcdefgh
```

### Example Implementation (Python 3)

```
# Takes input from stdin in the form shown above (a grid of Unicode
# chess characters and dots). Prints True if reachable. Prints False
# and the first rule number which is violated if unreachable.

import sys
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

Piece = namedtuple('Piece', ['color', 'type'])

# Read in the data from stdin.
data = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    chars = list(filter(lambda x: x in ".♟♙♝♗♞♘♜♖♛♕♚♔", line))
    if chars:
        data.append(chars)
    if len(data) == 8:
        break
assert len(data) == 8
for line in data:
    assert len(line) == 8

# Parse it into a more convenient format.
translation = {
    ".": None,
    "♟": Piece('black', 'pawn'),
    "♙": Piece('white', 'pawn'),
    "♝": Piece('black', 'bishop'),
    "♗": Piece('white', 'bishop'),
    "♞": Piece('black', 'knight'),
    "♘": Piece('white', 'knight'),
    "♜": Piece('black', 'rook'),
    "♖": Piece('white', 'rook'),
    "♛": Piece('black', 'queen'),
    "♕": Piece('white', 'queen'),
    "♚": Piece('black', 'king'),
    "♔": Piece('white', 'king'),
}
for rank in data:
    for i in range(8):
        rank[i] = translation[rank[i]]

# Count the number of each piece that each player has, slotting
# necessary pawn promotions into their own category.
allowed = { 'bishop': 2, 'rook': 2, 'knight': 2, 'king': 999, 'queen': 1, 'pawn': 0 }
pieces = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for rank in data:
    for piece in rank:
        if piece is None:
            continue
        if pieces[piece] >= allowed[piece.type]:
            # Already have too many; it's a promoted pawn
            pieces[Piece(piece.color, 'pawn')] += 1
        else:
            # Count it normally
            pieces[piece] += 1

# Rule 1: Each color should have exactly one king.
if pieces[Piece('white', 'king')] != 1 or pieces[Piece('black', 'king')] != 1:
    print(False, 1)
    exit(0)

# Rule 2: Pawns cannot appear on rank 1 or rank 8.
for piece in data[0] + data[7]:
    if piece is not None and piece.type == 'pawn':
        print(False, 2)
        exit(0)

# Rule 3: Since we already put any "overflow" pieces at the pawn key,
# we just need to make sure we have at most eight pawns.
for color in ['white', 'black']:
    if pieces[Piece(color, 'pawn')] > 8:
        print(False, 3)
        exit(0)

# Rule 4: If we have both bishops and our pawns are all accounted for,
# then we have to have a bishop in each color.
for color in ['white', 'black']:
    if pieces[Piece(color, 'bishop')] >= 2 and pieces[Piece(color, 'pawn')] >= 8:
        squares = { 'white': False, 'black': False }
        for y, rank in enumerate(data):
            for x, piece in enumerate(rank):
                square_color = 'white' if (x + y) % 2 == 0 else 'black'
                if piece == Piece(color, 'bishop'):
                    squares[square_color] = True
        if not (squares['white'] and squares['black']):
            print(False, 4)
            exit(0)

# Rule 5: All pawns must be able to get to where they are. I solve
# this here by brute force (simply trying every possible permutation),
# which is exponentially inefficient, but it'll do for this example.
def recursive_assign(taken, choices, i):
    if i >= len(choices):
        return True
    current = choices[i]
    for x in current:
        if x not in taken:
            if recursive_assign(taken + [x], choices, i + 1):
                return True
    return False

for color in ['white', 'black']:
    starting_file = 6 if color == 'white' else 1
    choices = []
    for y, rank in enumerate(data):
        for x, piece in enumerate(rank):
            if piece == Piece(color, 'pawn'):
                possibilities = range(8)
                possibilities = filter(lambda i: abs(i - x) <= abs(y - starting_file), possibilities)
                choices.append(list(possibilities))
    if not recursive_assign([], choices, 0):
        print(False, 5)
        exit(0)

print(True)
```

### Proposed Tags

- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

### Sandbox Concerns

- I worry Rules 4 and 5 are still not clear enough. I tried to write
  them in a way that was as clear as possible while still being
  mathematically unambiguous.

Comment: too long. try to combine rules or at least don't draw so many of them in a column

Comment: If you're going to use unicode chess symbols, use a double-wide filler character instead of `.`. The alignment in your examples is off, making it very distracting. I'd recommend switching them to ASCII letters using the typical KQRBNP convention.

Comment: To add to Beefster's comment, in some fonts the chess symbols are not even double wide, they're somewhere in between. So double-wide fillers won't work either. +1 for ASCII notation.

Comment: if I recall correctly, you can have two bishops of the same color. Up to nine. By promoting pawns to bishops. Very rare indeed, but legal.
I want this to main page, though.

Answer (score 3):

## Road Sort Order

In Britain, road identifiers use [a scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain_road_numbering_scheme) of a letter, followed by a 1-4 digit number.

From Most-Important to Least-Important, the letters are:

> M
> A
> B
> C
> D
> U

The numbers also represent further assumptions around the importance of the road, such that a 1-digit number is more important than a 4-digit number.

Thus, the `M898` is *less* important than the `M8`, but *more* important than the `A8`.

*interesting but not relevant for the challenge - Roads are also sorted into nine `Zones`, of equal importance. The first number in each road identifier gives the Zone that the road starts in (e.g. `A8` starts in Zone 8 - although there are exceptions where one Motorway spurs off of another, e.g. `M48` is so named because it is a spur of the `M4` even though it is officially in Zone 5).*

### The challenge

Given a pair of road identifiers, identify and output which is the most important road. Where there is no difference in importance by the above rules (e.g "B4063" and "B1234") then either output is acceptable.

Usual I/O rules apply, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest bytes wins. There will be two inputs, and no invalid inputs (i.e. they will follow the rules, although they may not be actual real-life roads).

If you say so in your answer, you may instead output the least significant road (i.e. as long as I know which it is, you can do either).

You may take the input as a string, array of strings, or array of strings and integers as follows:

"M123M223"
["M123","M223"]
["M",123,"M",223]

#SANDBOX# If there are input formats that you think should/n't be allowed, let me know.

### Examples

- `A11,M2` -> `M2`(Motorways come before A roads)
- `M823,M89` ->
  `M89` (two-digit roads are more important than 3-digit roads,
  even though 89 alphabetically comes after 823)
- `A1262,A150`
  -> `A150`
- `U6340,D6340`
  -> `D6340`
- `M1,M2` -> Either
- `B100,C99` -> `B100`

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying sorting to just comparing two distinct values. Or even, mapping a value to a number so that the comparisons are right.

Comment: @xnor sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean only ever have two inputs?

Comment: Yes, like have a possible input be like `f("A11","M2")` with it being a decision problem to tell if the first or second one is more important. Or, just have us write a function `g` producing a number so that, say, `g("A11")>g("M2")`.

Comment: @xnor how's that? I've made it return the most (or least) significant road of a pair

Comment: Looks good! I'm a bit worried about the "any sensible format" since counting digits is important. Like, would a length-four array padded with nulls for missing digits count as acceptable? I think this would be you compare the number parts as a direct list comparison in some languages.

Answer (score 3):

## Generalized Game Theory KOTH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[Game Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) is a field of mathematics that is concerned with strategic interactions among 'rational decision-makers'. The main focus of game theory is the payoff-matrix.

A payoff matrix represents an interaction between two parties, and shows how many points a party can get if they choose different strategies. Here is an example of a payoff matrix:

```
             Player 1
             A  |   B
Player 2 +------+-------
       A | 3, 3 | 5, 1
         +------+-------
       B | 1, 5 | 2, 2
```

In this example, if player 1 chooses A and player 2 also chooses A, they would both get 3 points. If player 1 chooses B but player 2 chooses A, player  would get 5 points but player 2 would only get 1.

The above payoff matrix is an example of the [prisoners dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma)

### The challenge

Programs will face off in a round-robin tournament. Each round will consist of a randomly generated payoff matrix, with both programs choosing either strategy A or strategy B. Programs will earn points accordingly. The winner will be the program with the most points, with ties broken by source code length.

### Questions for meta:

- best practices for creating KOTH challenges?

  - language considerations? I'm most comfortable with javascript but am also capable of writing in python
  - is it better to limit a KOTH to one language? it's easier to manage but limits who can submit
  - or allow multiple languages? It allows more people to compete but is more difficult to judge
- Any comments about the overall problem?

  - Has this been done before?

Comment: 1-1) Either JS or Python should be fine. Both are popular here and you can share the controller's code on TIO so that others can easily run it. Some other KOTH writers tend to provide a visual interface, but it's completely optional. 1-2) KOTH is usually limited to one language since they have to compete through the controller. 2) I don't think it's done before. But tie-breaking by code golf is not a good idea (in fact, tie breaking is not necessary at all).

Comment: Also, if you're planning to run through hundreds of payoff matrices, it will be more interesting to allow the programs to remember previous matches, so the whole competition looks like a generalized [repeated game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_game).

Comment: @Bubbler In that case I will probably make the controller in javascript. And yes, the game will definitely be repeated and programs will be able to access the past history. thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

## Is my triangle on the lattice? [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Posted [on the main site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217488/is-my-triangle-on-the-lattice).

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck arbitrary precision multiplication

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

### Goal

The goal is to multiply two numbers in the shortest amount of cycle.

### The Input

The input is two numbers written decimally separated by a space. The number is NOT restricted by the size of the integer inside of the cells. The program must accept arbitrary sized integer

### The Output

The output is a single integer written decimally.

### Brainfuck variants used

Since the flavors of the Brainfuck is important in this challenge, you are required to use this flavor

#### Memory

The memory is an array of cells, unbounded to the left and the right, with 8-bit integer as the contents.

#### Input/Output

The input and the output uses ASCII symbol mapping. EOF is interpreted as \0 char.

#### Looping

The [ means that "check the current cell. If it's zero, jump to the instruction after the matching ]"
The ] means that "jump to the matching [." no cycle is taken in this instruction.

#### Cycle

Every instruction takes a single cycle every time it's executed except for ]. ] is a free instruction.

#### Reference implementation

For the reference implementation, use copy.sh with this option:

1. Cell size (Bits): 8
2. Dynamic (infinite) Memory: yes
3. End of input: char: \0
4. Count instructions

### Scoring

The winner is the program that is: (later number is for tiebreaker)

1. The program with lowest computational complexity (counted by using cycle metric as explained above, and in x where x is the length of the largest input in base 10) is the winner.
2. The program with lowest space complexity (counted by finding the rightmost cell reached by program)
3. The program that takes the least cycle to execute 1234567890*987654321
4. The program that takes the least memory to execute 1234567890*987654321
5. The shortest code

Computational complexity is determined in terms of the number of digits each arguments have.

Comment: [tag:fastest-code] is the winning criterion tag, so you don't need [tag:code-challenge]. To lower the obstacle before starting to work on the challenge, I suggest to use [the copy.sh online interpreter](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/) as the standard. (I think it satisfies the cycle count rule?)

Comment: @Bubbler Actually, I designed my challenge with copy.sh as the reference. The only difference is that the memory tape is not unbounded to the left.

Comment: You can set "memory overflow behavior" to "abort" for that.

Comment: @Bubbler It's not possible to have both infinite memory and abort as memory overflow behavior. I changed the challenge so that the memory is also unbounded to the left.

Comment: Can we make assumptions such as 'the number of digits in the numbers is less than X' or 'the number of digits in the number of digits in the numbers is less than X'?

Comment: @thedefault. No. The program must handle arbitrary sized number.

Comment: @Xwtek So it would be impossible to answer it in a flavor with 30000 cells of one byte each? I think the limit on the size of each number should be half of the number of cells (and thus infinite for flavors with infinite cells)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes, it's impossible. Maybe I'll make a challenge to minimize memory use, but for now, you have to use infinite flavors.
"I think the limit on the size of each number should be half of the number of cells"
Not necessarily, I bet you need much more memory than that.

Answer (score 3):

### [BF memory layout optimizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218690/69850) (posted).

See the notes in the revision history.

[*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: (upvote this comment if you want a variant with [fastest-code] instead.)

Comment: (upvote this comment if you want both a [code-golf] version and a [fastest-code] version.)

Comment: (upvote this comment if you want only a [code-golf] version.)

Answer (score 3):

## Secret ">" Stacking Challenge: cheating [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetris)

Sequel to [Secret ">" Stacking Challenge: grading](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209720/78410). You can skip the whole Background section if you already read the first one.

### Background

[Tetris Grand Master 3](https://harddrop.com/wiki/TGM3) has a hidden grading system based on the shape of the stack at the end of the game, which is called [**Secret ">" Stacking Challenge**](https://harddrop.com/wiki/Tetromino_art#Greater_than). It consists of entirely filling the lowest rows except for the zigzag pattern which starts at the left bottom cell and spans the entire width:

```
#
.#########
#.########
##.#######
###.######
####.#####
#####.####
######.###
#######.##
########.#
#########.
########.#
#######.##
######.###
#####.####
####.#####
###.######
##.#######
#.########
.#########
```

The board is graded by how many lines follow this exact pattern from the bottom line. Note that the topmost hole in the pattern must be blocked by an extra piece of block. If you consider the `#`s and `.`s as the mandatory pattern (blanks can be anything), you can get the score of 19 only if the exact pattern above is matched from the bottom line. Analogously, if the board matches this pattern

```
   #
###.######
##.#######
#.########
.#########
```

but not

```
    #
####.#####
###.######
##.#######
#.########
.#########
```

then the score is 4.

For this challenge, consider a board of arbitrary size (other than 20 cells high and 10 cells wide). We can grade the board for the same pattern: for example, if the board has width 4, this is the pattern for score 3:

```
  #
##.#
#.##
.###
```

and this is the pattern for score 10:

```
   #
###.
##.#
#.##
.###
#.##
##.#
###.
##.#
#.##
.###
```

### Challenge

Given the board width and the desired score for Secret ">" Stacking Challenge, pick a sequence of tetrominoes and generate the sequence of moves that will achieve the score. The Tetris moves can be represented in any ways that clearly specify where each tetromino is placed in which orientation, optionally along with the board state after each placement.

For the Tetris movement rules, we use simple permissive rule as in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211033/78410): you can place a tetromino anywhere (even in closed rooms), as long as it doesn't float in the air or overlap with existing pieces. Therefore, if you plan to use coordinates, you need to specify both x and y coordinates (the y coordinate should be counted from the bottom, as the board can grow upwards without bound -- or count from the top by also outputting the field height).

You can assume the width is at least 5 and the score is nonzero. You should theoretically support arbitrarily high score. The generated sequence doesn't need to be minimal.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Output example

For board with 6 and score 2, one possible way is as follows: (`A`s are the tetromino placed at each turn, `#` are existing pieces on the board, and `.` are empty cells)

```
......  ......  ......  ......  ......
A.....  #.....  #.....  .AA...  .##AA.
AA....  ##AA..  ####AA  #.AA..  #.##AA
.A....  .#AA..  .###AA  .#####  .#####
```

The above is a valid output format (you can choose any distinct chars/values in place of `.A#`). The following is also valid (although it is less obvious, it is indeed an unambiguous description of tetromino placements):

```
......  ......  ......  ......  ......
A.....  ......  ......  .AA...  ...AA.
AA....  ..AA..  ....AA  ..AA..  ....AA
.A....  ..AA..  ....AA  ......  ......
```

And this: (tetromino code, rotation, x and y coordinates from bottom left, 0 indexed)

```
S 1 0 0
O 0 2 0
O 0 4 0
Z 0 1 1
Z 0 3 1
```

And anything in between (e.g. showing tetrominos as a canonicalized matrix instead of a code). If in doubt, ask in comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Peel away the layers - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212068/66833)

## [Peel away the layers - Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212069/66833)

Comment: I feel like you could remove a lot of the complexity of the challenge description by just requiring robbers to crack the whole submission at once, and so you don't need to specify MD5 hashes or anything like that and you don't need to worry about rep/CW/answer chaining. This might also allow for creativity by creating 'misleading' chains of polyglots (you decode with lang A in a chain, you get `Greetings?`, but in lang B you get `Greetings!`). You should also specify whether multiple of the same language in a chain is allowed.

Comment: Also consider that answers of the form `echo "....."` would be valid, and reduce to The Programming Language Quiz. You might be able to ward off just replicating the original challenge by having a very strict set of allowed languages (eg. must be on TIO), which would force using the polyglot system effectively.

Comment: @Sisyphus I've sat on it for a few days, and I think that's probably the best way forwards, even if it does make the Robbers' jobs harder. "You may repeat languages" is already in the spec (now bolded). I don't want to have to limit the available languages/interpreters any more than I have to, as some of the best answers to the last challenge like this (TPLQ) relied on the more obscure interpreters, and limiting languages could ruin that. Given that this requires 2 languages minimum, and that `echo "..."` style answers probably won't be competitive, I think this should be different enough

Comment: Looks a lot better. You have my upvote.

Comment: You should limit the program size to fitting literally inside the answer, otherwise you might get unary shenanigans that make cracking literally impossible

Comment: @pxeger On second thoughts, I've decided to limit each program to 65535 bytes, just to keep it sensible

Comment: Does an inner layer have to output a full program, or can it print a function?

Comment: @pxeger Either is fine, I'll edit that in

Comment: So just to clarify, we don't need to reveal the number of layers, just the number of distinct languages?

Comment: "Free here means that anyone can use the program without having to pay to do so" - is it still free if they must pay with their time and sanity?

Comment: Did you mean `Robbers'` not `Robber's` chatroom - it's not entirely clear

Comment: @Sisyphus the robbers' task is hard enough as is, let alone having to deal with cops that may use 2 languages but have 15 or so layers, so I've edited it to consistently say that you have to reveal the number of layers,

Comment: @pxeger "Free" means per [site standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7822/66833), and yes, I've corrected that typo

Answer (score 3):

## [Calculate the inverse of a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213899/66833)

Comment: _n , nor n2, will never exceed the maximum value..._ and _The elements of M−1 will never exceed..._ Even under those assumptions, intermediate computations can exceed the maximum. So maybe it's better to say something more general, maybe along the lines of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18197/36398)

Comment: Also, matrix inversion notoriously causes floating-point error build-up when naïve algorithms (i.e. algorithms not specifically designed to avoid error accumulation) are used. This results in relatively large errors in the output. And those algorithms are likely to be the ones used in a golfing challenge (if the language doesn't have a builtin). So maybe you should add a note saying that it is sufficient if the algorithm works when arbitrary precision is assumed

Comment: @LuisMendo I've edited in "It is acceptable if your program fails for some inputs due to floating point issues, so long as the underlying algorithm or method works for arbitrary matrices." which I think should cover both of those points

Answer (score 3):

## [We're all unique in our own way](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212328/66833)

Comment: I like the idea, but I feel like there should be some incentive to make the byte requirement small, large, contain common bytes, contain uncommon bytes, etc. Is there any reason to pick anything other than randomly?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've decided to make the number of bytes allowed has to be unique for each answer (i.e. only one answer may allow 120 bytes etc.), which means that people will have to be more selective with how many bytes are allowed when posting new answers, as well as which of those bytes are allowed

Comment: Suggested edit: "The chain ends when 14 days pass with no new answers being posted **or** when all unique number of bytes have been used"

Comment: Also, there's no incentive to answer high no.bytes, as no one wants to have a high amount tacked onto their score.

Comment: Further, I suggest you add a "languages cannot be newer than 4/10/2020" to avoid sandbox sniping

Comment: Proposed scoring system: each answer is worth `257 - n` points (`n` = number of allowed bytes), highest score wins.

Comment: Does “each byte must be used a minimum of one times” mean you have to use every byte in the list? If so, I think framing this as a list of bytes you “can use” is misleading. Also, if you have to use 100 bytes, but your answer only needs 20, does anything stop you from just stuffing those remaining 80 bytes in a comment or an unused string variable? It might be more interesting if you force those bytes to have some function in the program, or get rid of this requirement and let people use a subset of the allowed bytes.

Comment: @Lyxal I've added in that ending condition. I don't think any scoring system that involves the number of bytes available will provide an incentive to answer with both high and low bytes, so I've changed the score to be the number of answers posted. I dislike banning languages in general, so I've only banned languages specifically designed to answer this challenge

Comment: @water_ghosts Yes, it does mean that, I've edited to reflect that. Nothing's stopping you from having portions of the code completely unexecuted, and requiring all code to be run is an unobservable requirement. Given how broad new answers can be in terms of language and output, I think it shouldn't be an issue with requiring all the bytes be present

Answer (score 3):

## The Great Code Golf Heist

*Alternatively, the most literal cops'n'robbers you'll ever see*

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

### Backstory

**Sandbox Note: This part will be specific to each thread, so I've provided each version**

#### Robbers

For the last few years, you and your team of robbers have been planning to rob the International Code Golf Museum (ICGM) of some of it's most prized possessions (rumour has it, they have a rare transcript of Dennis being outgolfed!). Tonight is the night that your plans will be put into action... tonight you will walk away with glorious riches and legendary artifiacts of code golf history.

That is, if you can actually manage to get in, loot the rooms and get back out without getting caught.

#### Cops

Tonight has been a quiet night at the Internation Code Golf Museum (ICGM)...too quiet for one's liking.

Of course, that's probably due to the fact that a bunch of robbers are rumoured to strike tonight and steal the most priceless artifacts from the ICGM's collections (we can't have them finding out the fact that Arnauld is a machine learning algorithm designed to answer challenges with Javascript, can we.  [that's a joke we love you Arnauld!])

It's your job to stop the robbers and make sure that not a single thing leaves the museum.

### The Museum

**Sandbox Note: This part is common to both cops and robbers**

Here is a map of the museum:

[image: Museum Map]

You may be wondering "hang on, what are the dimensions of that map?". Well the answer is simple: you don't need to know.

Movement around the ICGM is analogous to a Henry Stickmin game: in each room, you can either move to an adjacent room, or perform an action in that room.

Robbers start at the `Getaway Car` and can enter through either Hallway A or Hallway B. They then move through `Hallway A.A` then `Hallway A.B` or move through `Hallway B.A` and then `Hallway B.B`. Either way, they end up at the exhibition room. From the exhibition room, robbers can move to any of the treasure rooms which is where all the valuables are stored. After that, they make their way back to the getaway car to, well, escape and get away.

Cops are randomly allocated a position at the start of the heist, and can move wherever they need to.

**Sandbox Note: There's going to be a system where each room takes a certain number of "strides" to get from one end to another. This way, robbers with stolen items are "slowed down" a little and the cops have a bit of a chance to catch up**

### Stealing Treasures

**Sandbox Note: Robber specific**

Once you reach a treasure room, you have the oppourtunity to get your hands on some of the finest works the ICGM has to offer. There will be a selection of items to choose from, each with different values.  **Sandbox Note: I might add a part where there is a limit on how much robbers can carry**

However, items with more value impact how fast you can move through. **Sandbox Note: Something relating to the stride system here**.

But being the sneaky robbers you are, you have a few tricks up your sleeve(s). When moving through the ICGM, you can:

- Activate a trap that will slow down the cops (avaliable only once **Sandbox Note: Subject to change**)
- [Other things coming soon]

Once you get back to the getaway van, everything you have stolen is considered "safe" and counts towards your team's score. But once you're in the van, that's it... you can't go back for more.

Your team wins if you manage to steal items with a combined worth of `insert value here`

### Protecting the ICGM

**Sandbox Note: Cop specific**

In order to protect the artifacts of the ICGM from being stolen, you have a few abilities you can use against the robbers. You can:

- Apprehend a robber if they are in your proximity
- [Other things coming soon]

For your team to win, the total value of items stolen must not exceed `insert value here`

### The Catch

**Sandbox Note: Common to both threads**

The heist program will only be simulated *once*. That means that if your submission errors, you're out of the game for good. I mean, you don't see criminals replace the things they stole just to rerun the heist over and over to see how good they are ;P.

The heist will occur on `insert date here`. You can edit your submissions all you like until the time of running.

### The Controller

Coming soon.

## Feedback

- Seeing as how this is a first draft, there are bound to be flaws with things like the movement mechanics and cop/robber interactions. I'm more looking for first impressions and overall flaws in the challenge.

Comment: I can't wait to see the valuables you place in the treasure room.

Answer (score 3):

## Can I print my picture on {A,B,C}{0-10} paper?

The task is to find the smallest paper size on which it is possible to print a picture of the dimensions given in milimetres. The image will be printed without margins.

## Input:

Two numbers (bigger than zero) and a letter a, b, or c, for example:

```
290
200
A
```

## Output:

Paper size, for example:

> A4

Another examples:

```
218,297,a      A3
1,1,c          C10
9999,9999,c    ??? (error)
74,52,A        A8
31,44,B        B10
26,1100,A       A0
```

---

- Upper- and lowercase variants of letters "A", "B" and "C" are
  allowed on input and on output.
- The image can be printed vertically or horizontally.
- The values can be passed as a parameter or entered by the user.
- Width and height of picture will be always > 0, and letters will be always 'a', 'b', or 'c'. You don't need to validate them.
- You need to handle paper sizes A0 - A10, B0 - B10 and C0 - C10. If the image is too large, you can throw an exception, print an error or whatever you want, as long as it is clearly different from valid result and the application will not hung up.

Paper sizes, please ignore inch values ([source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#Overview_of_ISO_paper_sizes)) :
[image: Paper sizes]

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Perhaps you should inline what sizes the `An, Bn` and `Cn` papers are. Also, some more test cases (~5-10) would be nice for the final version.

Answer (score 3):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214952/are-these-states-connected).

Comment: "Given a list of strings of two-letter abbreviations (see below) for US states, determine whether they are connected." So can we expect a python list? Or should we expect a comma separated list? I think you should clarify the input. Giving the input as a python list gives python (and any other languages that have the same syntax) an advantage over, for example bash.

Comment: What should the output be? Is it `<input> is not connected.` or `<input> is connected.`? Or can it just be true/false?

Comment: @nthnchu I think they mean a  list of strings, whatever that is in your language. I agree with using truthy/falsy for connected/not connected.

Comment: @Keba Are we required to compress the list, or take it as an input? If we need to compress it, add [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: Thanks for your replies. My idea was that the exact input/output format should not matter to much. Accepting a list of strings is fine but I guess just a long string such as "AK WA OR" or even "AKWAOR" is also fine – whatever works well in your language. And output should be truthy/falsy, yes. Thought that was covered by standard I/O rules but tried to clarify it.

Comment: @Razetime: Sorry, I am not sure whether I can follow. The code should output a truthy/falsey value for a given list of strings.

Comment: @Keba They are asking whether the list of states is provided as input or if we must keep it in our code. If we should keep it in the code, you should add the [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] tag.

Comment: @nthnchu The input should consist of a list of strings such as `["AK", "WA"]` (or something equivalent) and nothing more. The list of neighboring states, however, is *not* included in the input. Still, the output is not constant and hence that tag does not apply?

Comment: @Keba It still has the large constant string of the neighboring states. Look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) and [kolmogorov-complexity's info page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/kolmogorov-complexity/info) for more info.

Comment: Even though the output isn't constant is still relates to it.

Comment: From that page: ”a post should be tagged kolmogorov-complexity iff the bulk of the challenge is to produce a string or a subset of a dataset which is given in the question.“ I do *not* thing that the bulk of the challenge is to produce that string. First, that string does not need to appear anywhere and second, the main problem should be to decide whether the corresponding graph is connected or not.

Comment: And this question looks *very* different from the ones posted with that tag.

Comment: Yeah you're kind of right. Just wondering, is `["AK"]` considered connected?

Comment: It is, I add it to the list of test cases.

Comment: My case for the tag is that compressing the string is one of the only ways to win; I just completed the challenge in less bytes than the string in python because I compressed it.

Comment: @Keba Is `["AK", "OR", "WA"]` connected? (It's `["AK", "WA", "OR"]` in a different order).

Comment: @nthnchu: Of course. I also added another test case showing that the states do not need to form a line in order to be connected.

Comment: Apart from the question which tags are appropriate, I do not think that giving the list as input is too interesting, mainly because it is then quite similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/determine-number-of-connected-components

Comment: @Keba I’d explicitly state that the states don’t have to connect in order, they can be in any order but must all be connected when put together.

Comment: I do also want to note that this adds another level of difficulty because solvers will have to reorder the list or come up with a more innovative solution than just checking if one is connected to the next.

Comment: @nthnchu I think the definition of a connected graph should be well-known. I also (by my last edit) linked to the corresponding Wikipedia page. Is that not explicit enough?

Comment: @Keba I didn't notice the link, never mind

Answer (score 3):

## [Sociable sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220572/66833)

Comment: You probably need to describe what a proper divisor is. Separately, I'm not sure how great requiring infinite output is. I'd probably consider allowing another optional argument that limits how many sequences to output?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I've updated the challenge to be closer to the normal [sequence] I/O rules

Comment: So is 25 a 1-sociable number, since its divisors sum to 6, and then there's a cycle?

Comment: @user No, \$25\$ is not a \$1\$-sociable number. "They are numbers whose proper divisor sums form cycles beginning and ending at the same number". \$25\$'s "cycle" is \$25 \to 6 \to 6 \to \cdots\$, which does not begin and end with the same numbers. I'll edit that in though

Comment: That "begin and end at the same number" is unclear. (it's a cycle, it neither begins nor ends) Perhaps "the initial number is inside the cycle".

Comment: Should that "given value" be interpreted as "value that will be given as input"?

Comment: That "does not diverge" sounds like a terribly hard conjecture... EDIT indeed it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%E2%80%93Dickson_conjecture ("likely false"), and looks like that the sequence you came up with already have a name.

Comment: with that, it's problematic, you'd better specify that "If there are \$ n \$ such numbers, the answer must provably finish printing them all without assuming the conjecture" -- although for most approaches it isn't that hard.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly's Untruth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216734/66833)

Answer (score 3):

## [Generalised Taxicab Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216985/66833)

Answer (score 3):

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217278/87058)

Answer (score 3):

## Is it a Lobster Number?

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217960/is-it-a-lobster-number)

Comment: I like the idea, but the fact that prime numbers don’t count seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: It definitely is a bit arbitrary, but I felt that it made sense as an edge case, since while it is a prime factor, it is already the number itself, and there are no other factors. The related (but not identical) OEIS sequence also seems to have made this distinction, so it seemed reasonable.  It also has the simple explanation that lobsters are not needed to get the result for the prime numbers, and shouldn't be overly difficult to work around in golfing, as all you need is a single comparison (is there only one factor, or is the first factor equal to the number).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, and it's not a deal-breaker for me, it would just make writing an answer slightly more annoying :)

Comment: @user - Posted since there seems to be no general problems with the question.

Comment: Well, I don't see any problems with it myself, but it would have been good to let it sit a few more days to get more feedback

Comment: @user - I'll keep that in mind, this is my first question here, this site is quite a bit different from the other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

*Note*:

- as you can probably tell, this is a simpler variation; however the poster of the other sandbox post has not been visiting the site for a while.
- because of the current situation, I **recently** (after the 2 upvotes is made) changed the winning criteria. Is there any problem with the description?
- What info should be included in the header?...

---

### Efficient table-lookup computation

Posted: [Efficient table-lookup computation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218976/efficient-table-lookup-computation)

Comment: (ah, right. The sandbox is still as inactive as usual.)

Comment: Or it could be that the challenge is simply a little hard to read.)

Comment: If two answers have the same `A+B`, is the one with lower `A` or lower `B` considered better, or is there no tie-breaker?

Comment: @Dingus No, see the meta post about challenge having multiple winning conditions. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/is-a-solution-wins-if-theres-no-strictly-better-solution-in-multiple-measures

Comment: There's no consensus on that meta question. I think you should state that if two answers have the same `A+B` then they score the same.

Comment: @Dingus +1 is not a consensus?

Comment: A post is considered as a consensus only if it's at `>= +10` and `upvotes >= 2*downvotes`. So +5/-4 (at the time of writing) is closer to a controversy than a consensus. I guess many people have just feelings without enough justification about whether it's fine or not. I personally view it as a good challenge, so I upvoted it.

Comment: A minor nitpick: In your Python code, adding string to a number is invalid. I guess you meant to take the inputs as strings, e.g. `m1 = "0"` etc.

Comment: For the lack of sandbox feedback, I usually leave my challenges for at least a week, regularly asking for feedback in the chat (at least 2 or 3 times before moving to main).

Comment: @Bubbler Fixed.

Comment: to me it looks like the given method to generate a single score from A and B only adds confusion, especially the "combined score" part... what's the advantage compared to a simpler formula like A^2+B^2? (I would be in favour of just using A and B and letting all pareto-optimal solutions win, but I understand that at the moment there's not enough consensus for this)

Comment: @Leo Because it doesn't encourage these solutions, obviously? -- (I think that the solution with minimum A is pretty interesting, but I'd like to see a solution that generates reasonably-good parametrized solutions too.)

Comment: @Leo as explained in the linked meta post -- (did I explain it clearly enough?) that method would allow essentially the same "every solutions win" situation by letting every such "winning" solution improves the "combined" score. (and is the only one that I can come up with with that condition)

Comment: The problem with the combined score is that you have two scores again, the "normal" one and the "combined" one... Does only one or the other count for "victory"?

Comment: @Leo Obviously the combined one. Note that the criteria is chosen so that the combined score is always better than or equal to the normal score, and the combined score is always better than the previous combined score.

Comment: So, by definition, all the solutions that is not strictly-worse is "worth posting" (improves the combined score).

Comment: I see, I like it but it may need some clarifying. For example in the header I would put only the values of A and B and the combined score. Then I would add a clause like the ones in answer-chaining challenges: "Once there have not been any improvements to the combined score for X days, the last submission to improve the score will be accepted as the winner"

Comment: @Leo I don't plan to accept an answer anyway. The winning criteria is simply to give people things to do.

Comment: Also, it's not important, but why 10000 for the board size? At least for A there's a very easy upper bound of 365

Comment: @Leo Just an arbitrary value that I feel is large enough...

Answer (score 3):

## [Generalise perfect numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220032/66833)

Comment: Better having a statement "in this challenge \$\sigma^n(k) \$ denotes...". It can be interpreted as \$(\sigma(k))^n \$ too.

Comment: Can answers assume that "the sequence is infinite"?

Comment: @user202729 Addressed both questions

Answer (score 3):

## [What's the odd one out?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220460/whats-the-odd-one-out)

Comment: Looks like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558/i-double-the-source-you-double-the-output) but a bit more interesting

Comment: Great challenge! Seems ready to be posted

Answer (score 3):

## [Write an interpreter generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221128/write-an-interpreter-generator)

Comment: Can an input contain one or more operations? like `a + 1 - 4 * 8`? Is input guaranteed to be valid?

Comment: @Wasif editing the answer

Comment: Another suggestion, you might make it a [tag:code-challenge], where the objective will be to generate as short output as possible (Which means to golf the generated interpreter as much as possible), where the original source code length will not matter, so people can work for their code more peacefully, But [tag:code-golf] (original challenge) one is good too.

Comment: @Wasif hmm... not a bad idea at all. This challenge does seem more effective with the [tag:code-challenge] tag, I will edit that into the answer.

Comment: @Wasif on second thought, I'm not really sure how you would actually test the length of the output... it would not be fair for one answerer to test with a 100-command language while another tests with a simple 1-command language. Thanks for the suggestion, but [tag:code-golf] seems like the better option for now.

Comment: OK, also how would handle destructive input like `a / 0`, which attempts to divide the accumulator by 0, which would result into crashing the interpreter?

Comment: `the input is valid` doesn't seem like a good enough description, let me change that

Comment: "each command is one letter long." so, highest number of inputs are 26?

Comment: Can we pre-define the input array in the header section of Try It Online?

Comment: @Wasif yes, that can be inferred from that fact. Not sure what the header is, because I don't really use tio

Comment: Header section means the part where you write code, is not added to the byte count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121169/discussion-between-wasif-and-ophact). (Automatically comments were moved there because lengthy conversations cannot be run in comments)

Comment: I've edited this to a stub now that it's been posted

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly thank you, forgot to do that

Answer (score 3):

## [Keep PPCG running in Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221353/keep-ppcg-running-in-game-of-life)

Comment: "Minimally destroying CGCC", "Keep PPCG running". Hmm, someone doesn't like the name change :). May I ask why you have this proposal too, though?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Because the two tasks are different, and I very much doubt answers to the two will be trivially similar

Comment: Right now you could just place a glider in the box and it would run forever. Maybe redefine 'fixed position'?

Comment: @Ausername "If any spaceships or patterns of infinite growth are generated, the board will never reach a "fixed state" and such cases are invalid submissions." A glider is a spaceship

Comment: Oh ok, didn't see that bit.

Answer (score 3):

## [What's my TIO uniqueness?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222632/whats-my-tio-uniqueness)

Comment: Oops, didn't read that

Comment: Maybe you could say "undefined" instead of 0 in the sentence "The TIO uniqueness of a language for which this is impossible is 0". Also, do you want submissions to store all 680 language names in the code?

Comment: @Bubbler Changed to undefined, it fits better. Yes, submissions should have some way of storing the names, be it in an external file or in the program itself etc.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Given that there are 680, I think it may be impractical to include the full list in the question, which is why I linked to [this](https://gist.github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/504bd72c948aa83e0817f400dc53aee3) gist with all languages and their outputs

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the link.

Comment: "subsequence" tag? Why?

Comment: @tsh Because the TIO uniqueness depends on the shortest substring that isn't common with any other language

Comment: but substring is not subsequence

Comment: @tsh No, but [substring] isn't a tag, and [subsequence] is the best alternative

Answer (score 3):

## [cadaddadadaddddaddddddr - linked list accessing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/cadaddadadaddddaddddddr/221347#221347)

Comment: Yay, a lisp challenge! Does each 'a' mean a car and each 'd' a cdr?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI yeah, but I'm to lazy to have written a description in _english_ so far. I guess I'll get to it eventually :P

Comment: Fortunately the common lisp hyperspec already describes the bulk of it well.

Comment: You might want to make the reference implementation a link to TIO (unless it doesn't work on TIO, of course)

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Why? (I can't access TIO anyway)

Comment: Meh, I just don't like those code snippets, and it makes it easier to pull out of the question, modify the input, and stuff. These code snippets sometimes break for me. If you can't access TIO, though, it doesn't matter, of course.

Comment: [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/cadaddadadaddddaddddddr/221347#221347)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted

Answer (score 3):

[Un-pipe an Elixir expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222585/89930)

Comment: It's unclear what kind of expressions we have to deal with, but it looks good, and interesting . E.g. do we have to handle `expr |> function(with_one_parameter)`?

Comment: @Wezl I was thinking the expression could be anything with printable non-whitespace ASCII but I realize now that could be problematic. I'll change it to be more restrictive.

Comment: @Wezl I specified that you may assume all functions will take only one parameter, so you do not have to handle `expr |> function(with_one_parameter)`.

Comment: Why do some piped expressions have () and some do not? Are we meant to support both of these?

Comment: @Ausername It's to demonstrate that both are valid, but as I state in the rules you need only support one convention.

Answer (score 3):

### Limit of lists [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You're given a never-ending sequences of lists, each of which appends some number of values to the end of the previous one. That is, each list is a prefix of the next.

```
3
3,1,4
3,1,4,1
3,1,4,1
3,1,4,1
3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6
...
```

While some steps may leave the list unchanged, its length grows unboundedly, giving an infinite list in the limit. Your goal is to output this
infinite list.

Note that you can't know a-priori how many lists you must read to get, say, the 5th value in the infinite list, just that you'll eventually hit a list with 5 or more elements.

**Input and output:**

The list elements are digits 0-9. You may treat them as characters if you wish.

The input and output are both infinite lists. These can be represented in various ways, and may be different for the input and output.

- An infinite list or stream
- A stateful method or black-box function that produces a new value with each call
- Repeatedly reading from STDIN or writing to STDOUT, or file buffers or the like

A mapping from index to value isn't allowed for input or output. The output must be uniform, without chunks of digits grouped together.

---

*Sandbox: Infinite list I/O is hard. Any suggestions?*

Comment: "Your goal is to output this infinite list" - can you clarify that it's *by taking later elements from the lists that get later and later in the input list* - I had to read this several times to understand that. Also, while I don't think there's any getting around the infinite input requirement, perhaps you could change the output to standard [tag:sequence] rules to make it more flexible?

Comment: Is the first list guaranteed to be one element long? Or can it be any length? Can it (and any subsequent lists) be empty?

Comment: You should probably specify the intermediate output/s needs to be as soon as it's available from the input infinite lists, or at least in finite time, so noone can submit `tail -1`

Answer (score 3):

## [Rejecting invalid IPv4 addresses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223507/103069)

Comment: You should generally include the definition of things like this directly in the challenge rather than just linking to a Wikipedia article on it, so people don't have to go to an external site

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you used boolean true/false for "is this valid", rather than "invalid" vs "valid". You might also want to change [tag:classification] to [tag:decision-problem]

Comment: @pxeger Thanks. Included both suggestions.

Comment: Is this means the input should always be a string / list of characters? May I take input as an array of 4 integers / a 32 bit unsigned integer / a built-in type for IP address (if there is one)?

Answer (score 3):

## [diddly darn posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224235/execute-a-befunge-chess-board)

Comment: Tag [tag:chess]?

Comment: My god, this is amazing. I can't wait to see the full version!

Comment: It's not clear to me what should be output in the non-deterministic cases. Do we have to output all possibilites?

Comment: Addtionally, what do you want the result of this to be:

`,v, \n >,A  \n ^<B` ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eve3iWhL); is multline code possible in a comment?)

Rules as written I think it's a tie since the center cell is reached twice but it's not clear this is desirable.

Comment: @kops it's okay for the board to result in a tie.

Comment: And the point is to output the result of the board, which may not be deterministic

Comment: So each possibility has to be output with the correct probability in the non-deterministic cases? And for the specific board in my second comment, it's very much morally an A victory, not a tie, but the technicality of passing through the same cell going in different directions makes it a tie in these rules which I find a bit weird.

Comment: @kops no it is not the probability but the result of running it once. That result may vary. And even though that may seem like it should be a win for A, it could be the result of some clever play from B to trick A into thinking they've won

Comment: @Lyxal I didn't mean to say the probability itself should be output, but that for each possibility, the probability of that possibility being output has to be correct?

Comment: @kops you only ever output one result - the winner of the game when evaluated. Because there are commands that change the direction, it can be impossible to 100% tell who wins. I was simply pointing out that there is more than one possible output for such boards.

Answer (score 3):

## [Interpret control characters like a terminal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223558)

Comment: As "your program does not need to interpret backslash escape sequences - the input will contain the literal control codes themselves.", I'd suggest actually including the characters in the test cases, or at least including a TIO link (or pastebin etc.) with the literal characters

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing `\r` isn't really usable on the web because it will be converted to a newline, and most languages have their own literal syntax for entering those characters anyway, so I think it wouldn't really help

Comment: Suggest a `aaaaaaa\b\b\b\t` case, do TAB fill them space?

Comment: @l4m2 thanks - that helped me discover some subtle bugs in my reference implementation too

Answer (score 3):

## Rob the King: Hexagonal Mazes

Consider the following hexagonal maze:

```
     E . \ . . .
    . . . \ . \ .
   . . . . \ . \ .
  _ _ _ _ . \ . \ .
 . / . . . . . . | .
. | . . _ _ _ _ / . .
 . \ . \ . . . / . .
  . \ . \ . . / . .
   . \ . \ . . . .
    . \ . \ / . .
     . \ . | . X
```

`E` represents the entrance, `X` the exit. `|_/\` are walls and `.` are free spaces. In order to navigate from `E` to `X`, we can move to any free space in the up to 6 immediately surrounding spaces. The path from `E` to `X`, marked with `P` is:

```
     E P \ P P P
    . . P \ P \ P
   . . . P \ P \ P
  _ _ _ _ P \ P \ P
 . / . . . P P P | P
. | . . _ _ _ _ / . P
 . \ . \ . . . / . P
  . \ . \ . . / . P
   . \ . \ . . . P
    . \ . \ / . P
     . \ . | . X
```

This isn't the only path, but the others are trivial variations on it.

---

## Cops

You are to write a function in Python 3 which takes a positive integer \$n \ge 2\$ and returns a hexagonal maze of side-length \$n\$, as shown above. The maze will meet the following criteria:

- The only characters in the output are `EX.|_\/`, space and newline
- The hexagon is shown as a hexagon. That means:

  - The first \$n\$ lines will have one more non-space character than the previous line (the first has \$n\$ non-space characters), separated by a single space, and offset from adjacent lines
  - The first \$n\$ lines have one fewer leading space than the previous line (the first line has \$n - 1\$ leading spaces)
  - The next \$n - 1\$ lines have one more leading space than the previous line
  - The next \$n - 1\$ lines will have one fewer non-space character than the previous line, separated by a single space, and offset from adjacent lines
  - Lines may not have trailing whitespace
- The `E` is the first non-space character on the first line, and the `X` is the last non-space character on the last line
- There is at least 1 valid path that connects the `E` and the `X`, only moving from one free space to an adjacent free space.

How your program generates these mazes is entirely up to you. It could randomly places walls in the grid, ensuring there is always at least one path left, or it could only block the center row except for one gap, or anything else.

You may return either a multi-line string, or a list of lines. Lines should have appropriate space padding at the start, and may have a consistent amount of trailing spaces. "Consistent" here means either the same number on each line, or padding each line to the same length.

The Robbers will be writing maze-solving programs that try to solve your mazes, so you should aim to generate mazes that are somewhat difficult to solve.

This is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), you are under no obligation to golf your submission.

Additionally, you may submit multiple submissions. You may not include anything in your submission that attempts to communicate with other submissions, attempts to interfere with other submissions or the controller or anything that could be malicious. If you do, your submission will be disqualified

Empty mazes of sizes \$n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\$:

```
                                                                 E . . . . .
                                           E . . . .            . . . . . . .
                         E . . .          . . . . . .          . . . . . . . .
           E . .        . . . . .        . . . . . . .        . . . . . . . . .
 E .      . . . .      . . . . . .      . . . . . . . .      . . . . . . . . . .
. . .    . . . . .    . . . . . . .    . . . . . . . . .    . . . . . . . . . . .
 . X      . . . .      . . . . . .      . . . . . . . .      . . . . . . . . . .
           . . X        . . . . .        . . . . . . .        . . . . . . . . .
                         . . . X          . . . . . .          . . . . . . . .
                                           . . . . X            . . . . . . .
                                                                 . . . . . X
```

---

## Robbers

You are to write a Python 3 function that takes in the return value of a cop's answer. It may also take the number of sides, \$n\$, as an argument if you so wish. The input will only contain `EX_|/\.` and space, and newlines if inputting as a multiline string. It will either be a multiline string or a list of lines. Your function should handle both.

Your function should then output the maze with any valid path connecting the `E` and `X` using only connected free spaces. You may show the path with any character aside from `EX_|/\.`, space or newline.

This is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), you are under no obligation to golf your submission.

Additionally, you may submit multiple submissions. You may not include anything in your submission that attempts to communicate with other submissions, attempts to interfere with other submissions or the controller or anything that could be malicious. If you do, your submission will be disqualified

---

### Scoring

The scoring will take the form of a round-robin, similar to [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenges. Every cop will be paired up with every robber, and the following will happen with each pair:

- The controller will call the cop's function 5 times with \$n = 2\$ as an argument, saving each of the 5 mazes. The cop will have 1 minute to produce each maze
- It will then pass each maze to the robber to solve. The robber will have 1 minute per maze to produce a correct output.
- If all 5 mazes are correctly solved by the robber within 1 minute each, the controller goes again, but with \$n = 3\$, and so on, increasing the \$n\$ by one, until either:

  - The robber fails to solve a maze within 1 minute
  - The robber produces an incorrect solution to an input maze
  - The cop fails to return a maze within 1 minute
  - The cop returns a maze with no path

At this point, both the cop and the robber receive points equal to the highest \$n\$ that neither of them failed. If the cop failed, the robber receives an additional point, and if the robber failed, the cop receives an additional point instead.

If both the cop and the robber reach \$n = 50\$ without failing, they both receive \$50\$ points.

After all pairs have be run, the cop and robber with the most points are the respective winners

---

## Meta

- Thoughts? I'm not aware of any similar challenges that combine [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) with [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), other than [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51029/66833)
- Is this clear enough?
- Tags are [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), [hexagonal-grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid), [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze) and [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)
- Any further feedback?

Comment: If you want to automate the scoring process, you might want to restrict the I/O further, e.g. only allow stdin/stdout as a hexagon-shaped multi-line string. (I'm suggesting stdio because I assume you want to allow different languages.) Looks interesting, though I have a slight feeling that a full Dijkstra impl in C will almost surely win as a robber.

Comment: @Bubbler Good point, I've updated the I/O to be stricter.

Comment: @Bubbler I've decided to limit it to Python 3 functions, as I was struggling to make a controller that would allow any language to compete

Comment: It's a minor thing, but maybe change `E` and `X` to `A` and `B`? It seems more logical that way

Comment: @pxeger I chose `E` and `X` as "entrance" and "exit" respectively, but I doubt it'll affect any solutions as opposed to `A`/`B`

Answer (score 3):

[You are kinda Replacable to Me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223929/you-are-kinda-replacable-to-me)

Answer (score 3):

## [CDGLF:TMN2APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224787/cdglf-tmn-to-apl)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

### Meta questions:

- Is this a duplicate? <sub>(I've looked and there are several challenges with operator precedence, but there are large differences such as floor/ceiling and the output format)</sub>
- How can I objectively define "equivalent expressions"? Should I write a reference interpreter or answer?
- Would it be more interesting going the other way?
- [Should answers be required to reject invalid input?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57740855#57740855) Seems not
- <s>Should I</s> I've replaced the unicode operators `×÷⌈⌉⌊⌋` with ascii symbols `*/{}[]`.
- Is the exponentiation operator necessary? (It might just make the challenge more cumbersome because of its different associativity)

Comment: It was previously `APL2TMN`. I'm changing it to `TMN2APL` to make it more interesting.

Comment: TMN's `+-×÷` are left-associative, but in APL everything is right-associative. The equivalent of TMN `3-5÷2+1` in APL is `(3-5÷2)+1`; APL `3-(5÷2)+1` is `3-((5÷2)+1)`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about associativity. I don't think my grammar handles it, however, so I'm not sure exactly how to resolve this.

Comment: Also, I suggest to state the output format (APL) in the same way as you did for the input format (TMN), and state the precedence and associativity (for both TMN and APL) separately in plain English for those who are not familiar with parser grammars. And I think input validation is unnecessary here.

Comment: I think the Unicode operators definitely should be replaced with ASCII, because otherwise it's 10 bytes used on every answer. This would require you to remove or change the output syntax of exponentiation, but I don't really feel like it adds much tbh.

Comment: @pxeger I've changed it, and I agree.

Answer (score 3):

## Worst time complexity in under 100 bytes

[Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), typically represented in Big O notation, represents how long a program will typically take to run given some input(s), ignoring constants.

Your task is to do one of the following things, with the worst time complexity possible:

- Sort an array of integers
- Find duplicates in an array
- Find longest strictly increasing slice of an array of integers

**Tasks:**

All of the tasks involve taking one input, an array of items, in any reasonable format, and returning an array. If your language supports mutable array data types, this is an allowed output format. Assume all items in the arrays will be (not necessarily positive) integers.

If you choose sorting: You may choose to sort the array by minimum or maximum.

If you choose listing duplicates: You may include a duplicate item any number of times in the output; `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]` could result in `[2, 4]`, `[2, 2, 4]`, or even `[2, 4, 4, 4]`.

If you choose longest strictly increasing slice: Duplicate items do not count as increasing, so `[1, 2, 2, 4]` is not strictly increasing. The items do not have to increase by a steady amount; `[-1, 4, 14, 16, 17]` is strictly increasing.

**Rules:**

Your program must be 100 bytes or less. Your program should terminate in a finite amount of time. You can assume your program will never run out of memory, and it does not have to terminate before the heat death of the universe.

This is a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). The winner will be based on the average time complexity, with slower being better, followed by the best case and then worst case for ties.

Comment: Unfortunately, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197001/78410) broke all "irreducible" challenges. You can execute (almost) arbitrary code unrelated to the task without breaking the "irreducible" requirement.

Comment: @Bubbler Hmm, and I don't think irreducible is a sensible requirement for this either. It definitely makes more sense with bytes than time, along with pristine. I'll have to think about some creative limitations. Maybe unique bytes only?

Comment: Now this is somewhat too close to bignum computation challenge, since all the biggest numbers are actually a fast-growing *function* applied to some number. They can be trivially converted to take the length of the input, and then used in the algorithm in some way (or just discarded).

Comment: How about this: Choose a decision problem, and write code that solves it, within 100 bytes (or use a partially ordered score instead of a byte limit). Answers are compared based on the minimal time complexity of the problem, not the implementation. So if someone solves an EXPTIME-hard problem, they beat whoever solves a problem in P. This solves the problem of people doing useless calculations, since it doesn't help them. Writing a sorting function that takes exponential time is not in any way better than just doing a sort in O(nlogn) time.

Comment: @AnttiP That could be cool, but it sort of goes against what I was going for (ridiculously slow sorting algorithms). Maybe a separate challenge idea?

Answer (score 3):

## A Self-Referential Sentence

### The Story

---

One day, you decide that you want a sentence that tells you where in the sentence the letter T occurs (excluding whitespace and punctuation). Out of curiosity, you try to make one. Messing around a little you get

> T is the first, fourth, eleventh, sixteenth, twenty-fourth, ....

Oh dear, this sentence appears to run forever. But you now think you have an interesting number sequence, so you slap it into the OEIS search bar and lo and behold you find sequence [A005224](https://oeis.org/A005224), Aronson's sequence. And better yet, an interesting code-golf problem that no appears to have posed before!

---

### The Task

Your task is to write a program that takes in a single positive integer, `n`, as input and gives the position of the `n`-th "t" in the above sentence (indexing begins at 1 for the sake of this problem). For example, an input of `1` should return `1`, while `2` should return `4`. The input number will not exceed 4 decimal digits in length (i.e. the maximum input is 9999)

As always, the shortest code in bytes wins, and standard loopholes apply.

---

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

### The Meta

Ok, so I have a couple of questions, since this my first sandbox post.

1. What can I do to flesh out this problem? This seems short, especially for a CGSE prompt. Should I somehow flesh out the heading fluff? Or should I add something more to the task itself?
2. I was pretty thorough in my search of the sandbox and main site for similar problems, but I could always have missed something, so please let me know if this is a duplicate.
3. Is the 4 digit input limit reasonable? Should I raise it or lower it? Remove it entirely? Since I'm not providing a file with ordinal strings, it seems like having a restriction on the size of the input is quite important.
4. Finally, please let me know if there's any other glaring problems in this prompt, this is both a first draft, and my first attempt at a code-golf prompt (since high-school).

Comment: Nice first challenge! I'd suggest following the [standard sequence I/O rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) and allowing programs to output either the first \$n\$, the \$n\$th term or all terms. Additionally, forcing 1-indexing (for the sequence) doesn't improve the challenge any more than allowing either 0 or 1 indexing. I cannot find any challenge that could be a dupe through some searching, so this looks to be 100% original. Finally, I'd recommend including either test cases or the first 10 or so terms in the challenge body

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing 1-indexing is fundamental to the recursive definition of this sequence, as “T is the zeroth, third, tenth, twelfth, seventeenth, twentieth, …” is quite a different sequence (not just off by one).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I meant 0 indexing in the input, not in the position of the `T` (e.g. `n = 0` would output 1, `n = 1` would output 4, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Interpret Gelatin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224491/interpret-gelatin)

Answer (score 3):

## Count up to 21

21 is a game my teachers had my classmates and I play in order to kill some time. The game works as follows:

- All contestants stand in a circle. The aim is to count to 21, one by one.
- At any time, any player may begin the counting by saying **1**.
- The plays then continue the counting by saying the next number. However, if multiple players say the number at the same time, the count resets, and someone has to say **1** again.
- The first player who says **21** is "out", and the game begins again with the same contestants except for the "out" player(s)
- The final player left is disqualified, and the entire game begins again. The last player not disqualified wins.

We are going to run a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, where bots aim to play this game.

You are to write a function in Python 3 that takes a list of lists \$L\$ as argument. Each list in \$L\$ represents a round in the game, with the last element being the most recent. The \$i\$th element of each list always corresponds to the same bot. Each list in \$L\$ will contain \$n\$ integers between \$0\$ and \$21\$, where \$n\$ is the number of contestants left in the game. The lists are either all \$0\$s, or are \$n-1\$ \$0\$s and a single non-zero value \$v\$.

If a list is all \$0\$s, either it is the first round, or the counter was reset in the previous round.

That function should then return either:

- \$0\$, meaning that your bot stays quiet
- \$v+1\$, meaning that your bot is attempting to guess this round

And that's it!

---

The competition will work exactly as described above. The controller will run 100 games. Each game will works as follows:

- The first round begins with all \$n\$ contestants. They will count up to 21, eliminating each contestant as they count to 21, and resetting the count to 0. The final player left is then eliminated, and the next round with \$n-1\$ contestants is run. At the end, the final player left standing wins
- The player with the most wins after 100 games wins overall

You may not include anything in your submission that attempts to communicate with other submissions, attempts to interfere with other submissions or the controller or anything that could be malicious. If you do, your submission will be disqualified

If any game has more than 10000 rounds, it'll be terminated and no player will win.

---

### Example bot

This is Random:

```
import random

def bot(history):
	return random.choice([0, max(history[-1]) + 1])
```

Comment: Infinite loops might happen quite often

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Put a limit of 10000 rounds per game

Comment: [TNB Feedback link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57810563#57810563)

Comment: So, if next number is 21: Is there any reason a bot will not to say 21 in that round?

Comment: I feel like someone's going to just add a bot to say every single number no matter what.

Comment: @tsh If multiple bots say 21, none of them win and the count resets

Comment: Can you post the code to run the game so we can test our bots?

Comment: @fasterthanlight I haven't written the controller yet, so no

Comment: but if i will lost their turn if i dont say 21, and the worst case is a tie if I say 21? So any reason I try to be silent?

Comment: Because there's no reason to not say 21, infinite loops are probably going to occur no matter what. You might want to consider adding a rule regarding this to prevent infinite loops (or if everyone but 1 says a number the bot who said 0 can be eliminated)

Comment: Just wondering, is saving state between different turns allowed? Or between rounds? Or between games? You also don't seem to distinguish between rounds and turns (i.e times when the count resets vs. opportunities to guess), which may cause confusion. Also, a suggestion: Maybe let each game have only a small subset of the bots as contestants, so that if there's that one bot who always says 21 as soon as possible, it would just harm itself rather than ruining the challenge. (Sorry for this long block of text.)

Comment: Interestingly, this is completely different from the game of 21 I know.

Answer (score 3):

## [Generate a UK number plate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226446) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: I'd suggest saying `AANNXXX` or something like that instead of `AA12XXX` so it's clear the age identifier isn't always `12` (that's clarified later, but still).

Comment: Just a note: the last 3 characters can't be either `Q` or `I`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I thought that too, but I found no mention of it in the government document so I kept it as the whole alphabet. *shrug*

Comment: There's a `Q` in the alphabet for the first letter, but then you say _the alphabet, minus `IJQTUXZ`_.

Comment: @Arnauld yep, that shouldn't be there. Too much muscle memory from typing the alphabet correctly I guess :þ

Answer (score 3):

## [Time bomb KoTH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224969/time-bomb-koth)

Comment: Enforcing determinism prevents luck based winning, which I personally like. Adds a sense of balance.

Comment: Determinism also means anyone can run a simulation of the game on their own machine. The game then devolves into aggressive metagaming and iteratively updating one's bots to always beat the opponents'. If you decide to enforce determinism among the bots, you must have some outside source of randomness to prevent players from simply simulating the entire game and instead actually formulate a strategy that is robust enough to still work well in the face of unknowns.

Comment: I personally like a bit of non determinism to spice things up but then [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224737/103324) came along. So you have to be careful.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 yeah I saw that answer. In the current design, the array for the numbers selected in the previous round will be initialized with random numbers on the first round, giving the initial seed of randomness

Comment: Another thing to consider: high numbers will have very small winning chances, and the entire game is biased towards low numbers (they come first, they don't subtract much, large numbers take many points on explosion **vs** large numbers give many points on success). So all "smart" bots will choose `<= n / 2` numbers, but then the trigger will also be lower, so bots have to choose even lower numbers. That can lead to a case of [positive feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback). It may or may not cause problems, but it may be good to keep that in mind.

Comment: And to the determinism topic: a viable compromise between determinism and randomness could be made: making the only allowed non-deterministic part a seeded PRNG function provided by the controller. The PRNG seeds used for the official ranking are kept secret, but it's still possible to replicate the given match by using the same seed.

Comment: @FZs That's true. I may need to buff the reward for larger numbers to encourage playing them. Also about the determinism topic, after some searching I found some method to provide a seeded random, and I think I'm going to try that.

Comment: More about the determinism: I decided to decide the secret seed before the challenge starts and provide the hash to prove that I won't change the key mid-challenge.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 3):

## Distance between vowels

### Objective

Given two vowels represented in single IPA characters, calculate the distance between them.

### Vowels

Vowels are characterized by three factors: **Height**, **backness**, and **roundedness**. Here, all vowels have the three characteristics as integers.

#### Unrounded vowels (z = 0)

```
    x=0       x=1       x=2       x=3       x=4
y=6 i(U+0069)           ɨ(U+0268)           ɯ(U+026F)
y=5           ɪ(U+026A)           ʊ(U+028A)
y=4 e(U+0065)           ɘ(U+0258)           ɤ(U+0264)
y=3                     ə(U+0259)
y=2 ɛ(U+025B)           ɜ(U+025C)           ʌ(U+028C) 
y=1 æ(U+00E6)           ɐ(U+0250)
y=0 a(U+0061)                               ɑ(U+0251)
```

(I know, Wikipedia states ʊ as rounded, but official IPA doesn't specify the roundedness of ʊ. It will be considered unrounded for this challenge.)

#### Rounded vowels (z = 1)

```
    x=0       x=1       x=2       x=3       x=4
y=6 y(U+0079)           ʉ(U+0289)           u(U+0075)
y=5           ʏ(U+028F)
y=4 ø(U+00F8)           ɵ(U+0275)           o(U+006F)
y=3
y=2 œ(U+0153)           ɞ(U+025E)           ɔ(U+0254) 
y=1
y=0 ɶ(U+0276)                               ɒ(U+0252)
```

### Metric

Your metric \$d\$ shall fit the usual definition of metric:

- \$d(v,w)=0\$ if and only if \$v=w\$
- For all \$v\$ and \$w\$, \$d(v,w)=d(w,v)\$
- For all \$v\$, \$w\$ and \$x\$, \$d(v,x)≤d(v,w)+d(w,x)\$

As an additional constraint, the norm \$\Vert\cdot\Vert\$ induced by \$d\$ shall satisfy:

- For all \$x≠0\$, \$y\$ and \$z\$, \$\Vert(0,y,z)\Vert<\Vert(x,y,z)\Vert\$
- For all \$x≠0\$, \$y\$, \$z\$ and \$k>1\$, \$\Vert(x,y,z)\Vert<\Vert(kx,y,z)\Vert\$
- Analogous rules for the y-axis and z-axis

All of these apply only to the vowels above. All other inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

### Rules

- Input format is flexible. It may be two chararacters, or a single string containing two charcters. In any case, every input that doesn't fit in your format falls in *don't care* situation.
- Output format is also flexible.

Answer (score 3):

## Create word lightning [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230010/80214)

Comment: Trees can be taken in different formats, right?

Comment: yes, they can be taken in any suitable format.

Answer (score 3):

## Memory KoTH

Memory is a game where a bunch of pairs of identical cards are laid upside down, and you try to find pairs while only looking at two at a time.

In this KoTH, the way it will work is:

The game will be played on a 4096-item array, and the "cards" will be integers 0-2047.

Each bot takes its turn in order. It has access to the results of previous moves (Up to its previous turn), but their only storage is a single integer.

## Spec

The controller will be written in Javascript.

The bot has a move function, which must return two integers: The positions of both its guesses, in the form `[g1, g2]`, where both are integers between 0 and 4095, and must not be gone already (see below).

The bot has access to:

The most recent move of every bot, including itself, in the form of an array of `[g1,g2,r1,r2]`, where `r1` and `r2` are the first and second values revealed. The first item of this will be your bot's most recent guess, and the rest will be the other bots. This will be the global variable `prev`, and is readonly.

A picture of the entire grid, as a 4096-item array, left to right and top to bottom, where 0 means gone and 1 means still there. This will be the global variable `grid`, and is readonly.

An array of values that are gone. This will be the global variable `gone`, and is readonly.

A single `ArrayBuffer(50)`, a 50-bit set of raw binary data. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) for help on how to access this. This will be the property `this.storage`, and can be used to store data.

Writing to globals is banned.

## Game

The bots will take their turn in a predetermined randomised order.

If a bot's moves are two tiles with the same value, those tiles are removed from the game area, and that bot gets a point.

The game ends when all tiles are gone, and the bot with the most points wins. In case of a tie, the bot that is last in the randomised order wins.

Bots should be a Javascript object like:

```js
{
  name: "A bot",
  move(){
    // insert code here
  }
}
```

## Meta

Should I change storage limit or grid size?

Comment: Shouldn't the bot be able to see the values of gone items?

Comment: @CommandMaster True, will add.

Comment: This doesn't _really_ matter too much but if it were up to me, personally, I would change the storage limit from \$[1,2^{50}]\$ to \$[0,2^{50}-1]\$ so it's a bitstring of length 50

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Oh yes, that's what I intended.

Comment: What if two bots tie?

Comment: @StackMeter The one that is last in the randomised order wins. I'll add that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a `Uint8Array` rather than a Bigint? Purely for ease of use.

Comment: Also need to make it clear that writing to globals is banned, since that's a legal play right now

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Yes, writing to globals is banned.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 How would I format this Uint8Array? Like how many items would it need to be restricted to?

Comment: Up to you. It's just a more convenient method of storing data that's a certain size.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Actually, I think a BigInt would be better for this challenge, as remembering a single tile is 23 bits, which would be confusing to fit into a Uint8Array.

Comment: Just make it a plain ArrayBuffer and DataView. That's easier. I don't like using bit operations to extract data from integers.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Ok.

Comment: Are you considering giving the bot the result of its first guess before asking for its second? That would introduce a new layer to the strategy. Eg. explore on the first move and defend or attack on the second

Comment: @EnderShadow8 I considered that, but it would become a bit confusing to deal with the other bots' perception of this.

Comment: How so? It seems like your current spec can already handle that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124510/discussion-between-a-username-and-endershadow8).

Answer (score 3):

## [But, Is It Art?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229445/but-is-it-art)

Comment: I think it is clear, but the second example of "is not equivalent to" is a little unnecessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

## [I'm Lazy: Close my Parens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/im-lazy-close-my-superparens/229189#229189)

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string)[lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisp)

Comment: It's clear what to do with `]`, but what does `[` represent? Is it the same as just `(`?

Comment: Why is `([(]` invalid but `[(]` is not? Will there ever be multiple `]` in a row?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem `([(]` is invalid because it is the same as `[(]` but with an unmatched `(` at the beginning since the `]` only closes the `[`. There may be multiple `]` in a row.

Comment: So basically `]` matches as many open parens as possible until it hits a `[` at which point it has to stop?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem yes. Should I add that to the question for clarity?

Comment: Yes, I think that would help.

Comment: Not sure if lisp tag is appropriate, because the challenge itself doesn't have to do with lisp.

Comment: Tag: [tag:balanced-string]?

Comment: @pxeger nice tag-finding skills :) I'll add that.

Comment: @qwr How else do I get the tag badge :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Write a C++ demangler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229918/94093)

Comment: Is `_ZN3foo3barE3baz` -> `foo(bar)::baz` valid?

Comment: That would be `foo::bar::baz`. The base identifier is `baz`, and it is prefixed with the namespace `foo::bar`.

Comment: Won't `foo::bar::baz` be `_ZN3fooEN3barE3baz` or `_ZNN3fooE3barEbaz`?

Comment: No, nested namespaces are placed together without a separator.

Comment: Decided to remove the "if it doesn't start with `_Z`, then it is to be printed as-is" as that adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 3):

## Generalised multi-dimensional chess knight's moves [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229624)

Comment: You know that the necessary conclusion is we do all the pieces - take my +1 and start the chain.

Comment: @StackMeter I don't think most of the pieces would be very interesting. Pawns in combination with details of what pieces are already on the board, maybe. Otherwise, it's just this challenge with some slightly simpler vectors

Answer (score 3):

## [Jump trajectory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230012/jump-trajectory)

Answer (score 3):

## [Reconstruct a recursively prime-encoded integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230243/66833)

Comment: Looks great! At first glance seems easy but it's actually a little more difficult. I think it's ready to post, although you might want to wait a day or so.

Answer (score 3):

## [Splinter metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231266/splinter-metagolf)

Comment: An example for a short repetitive string would be nice

Comment: @pxeger Ok, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3):

[Posted! - How many Sets are there?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231876/how-many-sets-are-there)

Comment: Minor suggestion: Move the expected outputs to the start, because you have to scroll all the way to the end to see them.

Comment: @user Done, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Visual Encoding

I want to create a program to randomize certain words, however, I would like all the swapped letters to have the same form factor as the previous one.

##### Challenge

Given a string of only lowercase letters (and no spaces), randomize its letters according to the following groups:

```
1: acemnorsuvwxz
2: bdfhiklt
3: gpqy
```

Each letter cannot be transformed into the same letter as it started as. Additionally, choosing the new character must be uniformly random (within codegolf guidelines).

One final thing is that for the letter `j`, it must be transformed into either group 2 or group 3, and this can be done by either:

Uniformly choosing between each group and then uniformly choosing a letter **or** Uniformly choosing between any of the letters in both groups

*Note that nothing can turn into `j` itself.*

##### Examples

```
helloworld -> kadfrszmhl
jamaica -> genokac
jamaica -> penokac
abpj -> odyt
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to create the shortest answer in bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Find the necessary Files

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)[black-box-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-box-function)

Let's assume you have program that needs *some* of the files in a given folder to run. But not all the files in this folder are actually necessary. You can only find out which are necessary be removing/adding files from/to that folder, running the program and then observing whether it runs or throws or fails. The goal is finding exactly the necessary set of files with the minimial number of calls to the program.

Let's formalize it a little bit:

You are given a black-box-function \$ f: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\} \$ that is of the form \$f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i \in I} x_i\$ where \$I\subseteq \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}\$.

Your goal is finding \$I\$.

Your program may only interact with \$f\$ by evaluating it at various \$x \in \{0,1\}^n\$.

Your score is \$ S= \prod_{m=1}^M (1+s_k)\$ where \$s_k\$ is the number of evaluations of \$f\$ you needed for the example \$k\$ in the test battery. The least score wins.

#### Test Battery

**META:** Not sure yet if I should explicitly define a test battery or just let participants iterate through *all* possible functions up to some \$n\$.

In the following list, the first column represents \$n\$ (the number of arguments) followed by the set \$I\$:

```
n  | I
3  | 1
3  | 1 3
3  | 1 2 3
4  | 2 3 4
10 | 1 3 5 6 7 9
```

The last entry for instance represents the function \$ f(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{10}) = x_1 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_5 \cdot x_6 \cdot x_7 \cdot x_9\$

Comment: Could the title have the "files" removed to be more abstract (or use another analogy)? On the surface this might look like a [tag:filesystem] question

Answer (score 3):

## Parse some Husk (WIP)

[Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) is a "functional golfing language inspired by Haskell." Its syntax is prefix, albeit with a twist: Husk's functions can be curried: so uses its static typing to determine how many arguments a function should take at a time. For example, Husk can tell that `m+2:2;3` should be parsed as `m(+2)(:2(;3))` and not, say, `m(+2(:2(;3)))` or `m(+)(2:2;3)`, which are meaningless.

## Task

This challenge involves validating a subset of Husk that has 5 functions and two types: integers 0-9 or lists of those integers. It also does not have parentheses or overloading. Your submission will take a string consisting only of the characters `mo;:+0123456789` and determine whether it is a valid program according to the rules below.

In the following descriptions, "unary integer function" refers to a function that takes an integer and outputs another. It's a made-up term, let me know if there's a better one. "list" refers to a list of integers, and "integer" refers to an integer `0-9`. You don't need to understand the purposes of each function, just the types of their inputs and outputs.

- `0-9` are values/integers.
- `;` is the unary function `singleton`. Its argument is an integer `x`, and it returns a list (`[x]`).
- `:` is the binary function `prepend`. Its first argument is an integer `x` and the second is a list `l`. It returns `x` prepended to `l` (`[x, ...l]`).
- `m` is the binary function `map`. Its first argument is a unary integer function `f` and the second a list of integers `l`. It returns `[f(l[0]), f(l[1]), ..., f(l[-1])]`.
- `o` is the trinary function `compose`. Its first argument is a unary integer function `f` and the second a unary integer function `g`. The third is an integer `x`. It returns `f(g(x))`.

Here is what their types might look like in Haskell:

```
(;) :: Int -> [Int
(:) :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
m :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
o :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

Here is pseudo-pseudo-pseudo-not-even-BNF-anymore:

```
<int> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | + <int> <int>
<list> ::= ; <int> | : <int> <list> | m <unary-int-int> <list>
<unary-int-int> ::= o <unary-int-int> <unary-int-int>
<valid-husk-program> ::= <int> | <list>
```

## Questions for Meta:

- Is this collection of functions okay? Should I add more or replace/remove some?
- Is this challenge interesting?
- Is this a dupe?
- Is the explanation good enough? How can I make it clearer?
- This currently doesn't have a lot of variety in the currying. Should the functions given to map/compose also be allowed to input/output lists? (and if so, would lists be allowed to be nested?)
- Can Perl regex do this? I'm making this challenge hoping that it can't.

Comment: You haven't really specified what the output is. The closest is saying the task is to "validate", but what do we actually need to do?

Comment: are we validating or executing(akin to the gelatin challenge)?

Answer (score 3):

## [Light-Cycle KotH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235504/101522)

Comment: I'd recommend removing all bots that crash in the same turn. Basing it off of external factors like submission dates is a bit unfair.

Comment: My justification for removing only 1 per turn is that it simplifies the logic of generating a leaderboard and removes some edge cases, otherwise things like 3-way ties for first place might be possible if all the bots crash at the same time.

Comment: I feel like biasing the rules against newer submissions is fair. After all, new submissions inherently have the advantage that they're able to see the older submissions and can strategize around these existing submissions.

Comment: The issue is that the oldest submissions functionally move first, meaning that being the first bot posted is a significant advantage.  What about edits?  If a bot is changed, does it drop to the bottom?  I agree that removing all bots which crash is the right call.

Comment: Hmm... I was going to disallow edits, so that anyone who wanted to update their bot must instead post it as a new bot. @Spitemaster Are edits typically allowed for KotH submission?

Comment: Frequently; not always.  But you've still got the problem of earlier entries effectively moving first.  If you really want to do it this way, it doesn't make sense to have simultaneous movement (because it's not really simultaneous).

Comment: Ok, that seems fair, I will update post to allow for simultaneous movement

Comment: If I were you, I'd consider sizing the arena based on number of bots.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable suggestion, what kind of scaling do you think would be good? I'm thinking maybe something like a square with side-length 2n+6, for n players.

Answer (score 3):

## Volume of a 3d model

In this challenge, you'll take a shape as input, consisting of a number of triangles forming an outer shell. Your task will be to find the volume of the resulting shape.

You can assume the triangles all connect to exactly one other triangle per side, and the surface does not cross over itself. You will not get an input where two separate solids touch only at points or edges.

**Test cases and sample implementation coming soon**

Comment: I like this one.  I think that its got some tricky bits to it, like getting the normals for the triangles and ensuring that they are facing the right way.  As far as input format goes, an Ascii stl file may be a good option, as it breaks down the meshes into faces and provides the normals as well.

Comment: is the winding of the input going to be consistent or could it be random? also what is the error bound for the output?

Comment: @donbright Random, I'm thinking. For the output, floating point errors are fine, as long as the calculations would theoretically return the correct result.

Comment: sounds like a good bit of fun but i kind of predict people will ask for some kind of precise bounding on the error like +/- 1 percent or something.

Comment: @donbright The answer could be off by a thousand percent, if I reimplemented the language with arbitrary precision floats and it worked, I'm fine with it. That's way easier for everyone. Answerers don't need to worry about weird floating point tricks, and I don't need to tell them their answer's invalid :)

Comment: i mean the question is how do you know the algorithm works without running it and comparing the result to the known correct value?

Comment: @donbright Probably a mix of trust, and it most likely being close enough to the correct answer that anything other than floating point errors is unlikely

Answer (score 3):

## [Pythagorean triples given the hypotenuse.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236378/pythagorean-triples-given-the-hypotenuse)

Answer (score 3):

## [Is This Scrabble Board Valid?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236406/is-this-scrabble-board-valid)

Answer (score 3):

## [Light it up](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239851/is-the-room-lit-up)

Comment: Maybe you can fill empty cells by some characters like `.` in your examples and testcases. Or it could be confusing: `L.#.` is falsy but `L.#` is truthy, but it is hard to see the difference.

Comment: @tsh Ok, thanks!

Comment: "some squares are walls, some are empty, and some are lights". Since there are testcases where only empty cell is there, will there be any testcases like `####`?

Comment: @tsh Yes, see the fourth truthy one. I'll be more explicit that some may not occur at all.

Answer (score 3):

### Leave ABACABA on the tape

*Note that will be removed post sandboxing: This challenge is Brainfuck-specific, but I hope that its contents make the reason why sufficiently clear.*

Write a brainfuck program which leaves the following sequence on the tape:

```
0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 4 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 ...
```

This sequence may be familiar to some as [ABACABADABACABA...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABACABA_pattern) or [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814).

Assume an implementation of BF with an endless tape and arbitrarily large (**but not arbitrarily small**) integers.

You should link to a visualizer to prove that your program works as you say it does, but if this isn't fast enough to witness the first few (say 4) numbers in ABACABA you'll have to explain it yourself.

This is code-golf, so the shortest program operating within these rules wins. Have fun!

Comment: Because a BF program would likely do destructive edits to the previous terms or add scratch data to the end while advancing the sequence, I'd propose a more rigorous definition: "Write a BF program where, given any prefix of the ABACABA sequence, running the program for some finite number of steps will give the pattern at the start of the tape."

Answer (score 3):

## Solve an Inglenook Sidings Puzzle

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[puzzle-solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-solver)

[Posted! After about 2 weeks in Sandbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238172/solve-an-inglenook-sidings-puzzle)

Comment: "Model railroading", not "railroad modeling?"

Comment: @Bubbler specifically model railroading. The puzzle was made to create operational interest on small layouts, since it only needs 2 switches and 4 pieces of relatively short track

Comment: So this challenge proposal has been in here for just about a week now; are there any flaws in this? I don't want to post this to the main site and get feedback that should've been caught in meta

Answer (score 3):

## [Write a number in overflowed binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238102)

Comment: Maybe define a overflowed binary number a binary number where one or more of it's digits goes over 1?

Answer (score 3):

## Sum powers to n

[Posted to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238146/sum-powers-to-n)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nth FizzBuzz Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/239702/66833)

Comment: Maybe allow any different 4 distinct inputs for `Fizz`, `Buzz`, `FizzBuzz` and `Number`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Shrink ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241412/shrink-ascii-art)

Comment: convert like `---, 3` to `[---, 3]`?

Answer (score 3):

## Print □□Square□□ Numbers

Your task is to write a program or function that accepts an integer as input/argument and prints/returns all square numbers from 0 up to but not including n².

But the numbers should not just be perfect squares in the mathematical sense. They should be square in *every* sense. That is, the digits should

- • occupy a square space, 5 lines by 5 columns (including separating space)
- • form right angles at their joints
- • be formed entirely from □ and space characters

Actually, the digits must be shaped exactly like these:

```
   □ □□□□ □□□□ □  □ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ 
   □    □    □ □  □ □    □       □ □  □ □  □ □  □ 
   □ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□    □ □□□□ □□□□ □  □ 
   □ □       □    □    □ □  □    □ □  □    □ □  □ 
   □ □□□□ □□□□    □ □□□□ □□□□    □ □□□□ □□□□ □□□□
```

Note the single column of space between each digit. Spaces at the end of each line are optional. (The three empty columns of spaces on the left side of the digit 1 are not optional.)

Each square number shall be printed on exactly 5 lines using these digits, and between each of these numbers shall be a single line containing no non-whitespace characters. You may optionally include extra blank lines at the beginning or end of the output.

Standard loopholes etc. Shortest solution in bytes is the coolest of beans.

Example Output (given the input 5):

```
□□□□
□  □
□  □
□  □
□□□□

   □
   □
   □
   □
   □

□  □
□  □
□□□□
   □
   □

□□□□
□  □
□□□□
   □
□□□□

   □ □□□□
   □ □
   □ □□□□
   □ □  □
   □ □□□□
```

(Note for sandbox: I know this is a good challenge because I had fun solving it myself. But I am worried there is another challenge I haven't seen that is too similar. Please let me know. I'll abandon it if so.)

Comment: Can't find any dupes on [this search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number%2bascii-art?tab=newest&page=1&pagesize=15) so it is probably clear.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117711/displaying-n-with-n)

Comment: @pxeger yeah that's probably similar enough not to post this

Answer (score 3):

## Expand a Rubik's Cube Commutator

Tags: [rubiks-cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Posted: [Expand a Rubik's Cube Commutator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240972/expand-a-rubiks-cube-commutator)

Comment: What do you mean by "expand" the commutator? Also, 3x3x3*, a 3x3 would be a rubik's square :)

Comment: @thejonymyster The common names for Rubik's cubes are by the size of a face since they're usually cubes, so we just call them "3x3" for a 3x3x3 cube, etc. Only in cuboids like the [3x3x4 cuboid](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cube334.htm) actually have the 3rd dimension

"Expanding" the commutator == Listing out all the moves performed in the commutator

Comment: ahh, that makes sense, for both parts. +1

Comment: "Each part of the commutator can be a separate value" - I see this is to make IO more flexible than flat string to flat string, which is good, but I would go further and allow the moves themselves be separate values in each part, and allow a list of moves as the output in order to focus on the challenge itself.  This would allow, for example, `[["F'", "U2", "R"], ["D", "B2"]]` -> `["F'", "U2", "R", "D", "B2", "R'", "U2", "F", "B2", "D'"]`.

Comment: I couldn't resist and just gave it a go in [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) and got a 15 byte solution (assuming IO is further relaxed as I suggested, which I believe you will do given your current relaxation). This is a good challenge IMO.

Answer (score 3):

## [Reversed Multiple Pair](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241992/reversed-multiple-pair)

Comment: maybe give an example and a step by step of evaluating if it is reversed multiple?

Comment: @thejonymyster Done

Comment: really simple, but it is clearly specified.  seems like a decent easy challenge. To make it slightly more difficult you can make this a challenge of finding all  reversed multiple pairs under a given limit.

Comment: @Razetime https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/105116?

Comment: it's your choice whether that change makes it more interesting or whether it is an unnecessary burden.

Answer (score 3):

## [Highlight a Wordle guess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241723)

Comment: confused to be honest . maybeeee abit too hard?

Comment: @DialFrost Can you be more specific? What part are you confused about?

Comment: er mostly about the highlighting value

Comment: @DialFrost do you mean: 1) you don't understand when to highlight the letters in which colour; or 2) you don't understand how the output values used for highlighting can be chosen? Or something else?

Comment: both i dont understand

Comment: @DialFrost without some more details on what you're missing, I can't help you to understand or clarify the description. What bits you *do* you understand?

Comment: pretty much none i just meant i dont understand the hilighting value and how it works the most

Answer (score 3):

## Will the tower balance?

You are given as input a tower made of bars of unit height, and your task is to decide if the tower is stable. Here is an ascii art drawing of a tower:

```
 #
####
# ####
#####
```

For extra clarity here is the same tower but with the different bars in different characters:

```
 A
BBBB
C DDDD
EEEEE
```

The bars are rigid, but they are not connected to each other. Even though the bars are not connected, they stay still under the influence of gravity. Here however is a tower that is not stable:

```
      B
CCCCCCCC
   D
  EEE
FFFFFFFF
```

In this tower, under the influence of gravity, the top bar will fall to the right.

The following tower is metastable:

```
AA
B
```

The center of mass of the A-bar lies on top of the edge of the B-bar. In this kind of situation the tower is considered unstable, since even a small perturbation will cause it to fall eventually.

## Input/output format

The input format is an ascii drawing of the tower like so:

```
 ###
  #
### #
```

In this picture there are 4 bars. It is guranteed that all bars are on top of another bar or on top of the ground and that every row has at least one bar. You can use a different printable ascii character instead of `#`. You can also take a 2d array instead of a string and use two distinct values for `#` and  . In that case please use simple values, that don't encode extra information (standard loopholes prohibited).

Output two distinct values for STABLE and UNSTABLE.

## Test cases

```
#
```

STABLE

```
###
 #
 ##
  #
```

UNSTABLE

```
  ###
 ###
###
```

UNSTABLE (metastable)

```
#
#     ######
####    ##
 #      ##
```

STABLE

```
###
 #
#####
 #
```

STABLE

```
 #
#####
 #
```

UNSTABLE

```
######  #
 #  #   #
### #####
 #   #
 #####
   #
```

STABLE

Comment: The rules do not actually specify what makes a tower stable. The stable test cases use balancing methods not stated anywhere, and the rules themselves just seem to be more examples. As a non physicist, "use gravity" isn't enough information IMO. This is a cool idea though and +1 once that's fixed

Comment: Just highlighting the bars on their own would be interesting IMO

Answer (score 3):

## [Recursive palindromes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241338/recursive-palindromes)

Answer (score 3):

### [Is this continuous terrain? Part II](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241609/is-this-continuous-terrain-part-ii)

Comment: i like it emanresu A!

Answer (score 3):

**Shanghai ascii game sticks**
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241708/84844)

Comment: Looks great, ready to post

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired thanks, I still got something to tweak.. I'm gonna take some time

Comment: How are the last two testcases possible?

Comment: @emanresu A the last test case is an edge case were 4 sticks are all bounded and one sits by itself and satisfy the one and only one stick removable condition, you are not required to remove all sticks but just the first

Answer (score 3):

## [Only one from each set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241627/only-one-from-each-set)

Comment: "There are no gaps in the numbers " does it means that the input flattened must contain all the numbers [1..n] where n is the maximum number in it?

Comment: @AZTECCO Yes, exactly

Comment: Ok, i think you should explain it, careful.. there are some test cases non valid. I think you may also specify that inner lists are sorted (if it's so I guess)

Answer (score 3):

[Cubax Folding Game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242578/cubax-folding-game)

Answer (score 3):

## Happy new year string builder

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242683/happy-new-year-string-builder).

Comment: The regex should probably be `/^(have a )?happy new year( to you)?!*$/i` (removed unnecessary grouping, added string start and end match, and the `i` tag means the search is case `i`nsensitive by default.)

Comment: @hakr14 thanks, editing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## The Con Man

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

The bots start with a balance of 100 points each. Each round is a 1v1 between two bots. One bot is the Proposer and the other is the Receiver.

P provides R with two numbers: think of it as a loan and repayment with interest. For example, P could propose (50, 60) which means that P wants to swap 50 points for 60 points with R. P also decides whether or to scam R. If R accepts, P can scam R by not upholding their end of the deal and instead taking the 50 points outright.

The twist is, R can see the outcomes of past transactions of P to determine whether or not to trust P and accept the offer.

The format of the tournament is that of a round robin where every bot will play P and R the same number of times against all opponents, in an unspecified order.

Whichever bot ends up with the most points wins.

The language of this challenge is JS.

Format (in TypeScript):

```js
type Bot = {
  R(
    offer: [number, number], // loan, repay
    opponentBalance: number,
    pastTransactions: [number, number, number][] // loan, repay, outcome (0 -> accept, 1 -> reject, 2 -> scam)
  ): boolean,
  P(
    opponentBalance: number,
    pastTransactions: [number, number, number][]
  ): [number, number, boolean] // [loan, repay, scam]
}
```

### Meta

- Does this make for diverse enough strategies to be worthwhile?
- Should more or less information about the opponent be supplied to the players?

Comment: And if the bot runs out of money, does it die or can it take a loan? It can't give out loans obviously right?

Comment: @ophact I think it should die since no reasonable strategy would accept a deal with a bot with no money.

Answer (score 3):

## [Largest rectangle in a skyline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242801/largest-rectangle-in-a-skyline)

Answer (score 3):

## Golfing Coins ([suggested rewrite](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243069/golfing-coins-in-a-board))

The challenge is to write a program that begins with a board like this:

```
O O X
O O X
O O X
```

The O's are coins. X's are empty.

### Rules

Every round you will uniformly randomly choose a coin and a cardinal direction. You will move that coin 1 spot in that direction, if there is an empty space there. Or in other words, moves must satisfy the following rules:

- The coins can  **only move up, down, left or right 1 spot.**
- Coins  **cannot move outside the board**
- Coins  **cannot overlap**

This process should be repeated until every coin has moved into each spot on the board. You should output the state of the board after every move.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: Still don't quite understand what is uniformly randomly choose here mean. For example, the board is `OXO/XOX/OOO`. If we first choose one coin, and then choose its direction, it will have 1/5 chance to chose the O in the middle. But if we list all possible moves and choose one from them, the middle one should have a 1/3 chance.

Answer (score 3):

## [Convert to UTF-∞](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243463/convert-to-utf-%E2%88%9E)

Comment: I believe if Unicode code points are used up. They are most probability caused by CJK characters. Until then, there are already >50% used code points represent CJK characters. And characters used by Chinese dialect other than Cantonese (HK source) are still missing in Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

## [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/243291/107299)

Comment: What is the order each rules applied? For example, for rules "11=12", "12=21", "22=3". If input is "1112", should it be "1112 -> 1212 -> 2121" or "1112 -> 1221 -> 131" or "1122 -> 1222 -> 123"?

Comment: All of them. See the original specification for Shue in the linked challenge, or the interpreter.

Comment: As challenges should be self-contained, I suggest you add the mathematical definition from my post (and maybe an informal explanation of how the rules are applied non-deterministically)

Answer (score 3):

## Draw an ASCII Volume

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243274/draw-an-ascii-volume)

Answer (score 3):

## Draw a Signal strength indicator

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243304/draw-a-signal-strength-indicator)

Answer (score 3):

## Ragged slice

Your task is to slice a ragged list. Your input is a ragged list and two lists of integers, corresponding to the beginning index and end index of the slice, where the beginning index is inclusive and the end index is exclusive.

## Explanation

Let's start from the very basics. How does regular slicing work? Let's say we have the list `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and we want the slice `[1,4]`. How does this work? Here is an illustration:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
  v v v v
  [b,c,d]
```

This means that `[a,b,c,d,e,f][1,4]==[b,c,d]`. Ragged slicing is a bit tricky, so please make sure that the previous diagram is mostly clear. Ok, now ragged lists.

Let's first just draw the indices like previously for the list `[a,[b,c],[d,[e]],f]`:

```
[a, [b,c] , [d, [e] ] ,f]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4
    0 1 2   0 1 1 1 2
                0 1
```

Now, let's see what a slice of [1 1, 2 1 0] would look like:

```
[a, [b,c] , [d, [e] ] ,f]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4
    0 1 2   0 1 1 1 2
                0 1
      v v v v v v       
      ,c] , [d, [
       c] , [d
     [[c] , [d]]
```

The last steps are probably the most confusing. But basically we want to do two things, in the following order:

1. Trim the left side until an element, or an opening bracket is encountered. Do the same on the right side, except with a closing bracket.
2. Balance the remaining brackets and keep the depth of every array element the same as in the input, by wrapping the output in brackets.

Now, let's look at what happens when we have empty arrays. In fact, let's replace every letter in our previous example with an empty array:

```
[[] , [[] ,[] ] , [[] , [[] ] ] ,[] ]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
  0   0 0 1 1 2   0 0 1 1 1 1 2   0
        0   0       0   0 0 1
                          0
          v v v v v v v v
          ,[] ] , [[] , [
           [] ] , [[]
         [[[] ] , [[]]]
```

Notice that for the empty array, the starting bracket doesn't have an index. This is because for an empty array, an index of 0 is already "one past the end" in an empty array, so there is no smaller index for the beginning.

If we would have used index `2 1 0 0` as the ending index, then this would have happened:

```
[[] , [[] ,[] ] , [[] , [[] ] ] ,[] ]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
  0   0 0 1 1 2   0 0 1 1 1 1 2   0
        0   0       0   0 0 1
                          0
          v v v v v v v v v
          ,[] ] , [[] , [[]
           [] ] , [[] , [[]
         [[[] ] , [[] , [[]]]]
```

Lastly, let's see what happens if the slice is empty. We'll use [1 1 0, 2]:

```
[[] , [[] ,[] ] , [[] , [[] ] ] ,[] ]
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
  0   0 0 1 1 2   0 0 1 1 1 1 2   0
        0   0       0   0 0 1
                          0
            v v v
            ] ] ,
```

Here after step 1, the input just disappeared. We'll just return the empty list `[]`.

## Rules

Your input will contain only lists (no numbers, letters, etc.), and the starting and ending index. Indices can  in bounds or one past the last in some array. Indices are non-empty lists of non-negative integers. The starting index is not greater than then ending index.

You can choose the order of the indices and also if they are 0 or 1 based (but they must be inclusive-exclusive).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

## Meta

This is a bit tricky to explain. If there were parts that were unclear, or poorly written, etc. then please comment. If you think there is a better explanation, please also let me know.

Comment: I don't get why sometimes the opening bracket is indexed, and sometimes not. Could you explain?

Comment: @pajonk I've added a paragraph explaining that. Basically it only happens for empty lists (that the starting bracket doesn't have an index).

Comment: Ok, that was a little confusing. Suggestion: replace empty lists with elements (like numbers) and disallow empty lists - wouldn't this be +/- equivalent and easier to explain?

Comment: I would suggest simply index any elements and the ending of an array. So for example, Array `[1, 2, 3]` is indexed as `[` 0=>`1` 1=>`, 2` 2=>`, 3` 3=>`​` `]`. And a slicing simply exclude the ending element.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hello Shue! (Cops)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243503/hello-shue-cops)

Answer (score 3):

## [Circular chained compound](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244092/circular-chained-compound)

Answer (score 3):

## [Remove unmatched brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245625/remove-unmatched-brackets)

Comment: "containing of brackets"->"containing brackets"? Also, what characters to expect apart from brackets? You may also want to specify that we want to match the closest brackets together (inferred from example). And I think you lost first `543` in your example.

Comment: @pajonk Fixed those.

Comment: What's with the `1` in the third testcase?

Comment: @ophact A typo.

Comment: "the input will only contain those and lowercase letters" - but the example string contains digits too! Could you remove them?

Comment: @pxeger Oops...

Comment: I think it would be good to add a definition of "matched." It may not be immediately obvious to everyone who reads the challenge why `[abc]def]` should result in `[abc]def` and not `[abcdef]`, since you could view either close bracket as being matched with the open bracket.

Comment: @DLosc Done. (filler)

Answer (score 3):

## Draw the Ukrainian Flag

[Draw the Ukrainian Flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/draw-the-ukrainian-flag)

Comment: "horizontally down the middle" -> "horizontally across the middle"

Comment: @att oops, fixed

Comment: Ginger u stole my challange idea :D (i thought it was too easy so i didnt post it)

Answer (score 3):

## [Resolve a Super Auto Pets Round](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245559/resolve-a-super-auto-pets-round)

Answer (score 3):

## [Interpret +-=](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245675/make-a-interpreter)

Comment: I would say this is a fairly simple challenge, but it could still produce some interesting answers. However, it definitely needs some more clarification on input specifications. Should code read from a file? Prompt for input once and interpret that program? Prompt for an input, interpret that, and then repeat?

Comment: @des54321 prompt, interpret, repeat, as i think that has more golfing potential

Comment: However I do realize that it won't exactly work on TIO... so idrk

Comment: A few things I think you should specify : Is this [tag:code-golf] or something else ? Can we assume input is always valid? Usually we do the task just once, it can be a full program or a function tacking arguments.

Comment: @AZTECCO 1. this... is code-golf... are you ok? 2. Yes you can.

Comment: Instead of explaining my suggestions in a comment I edited adding comments, feel free to reject anything you don't like. Hope it helps a bit.. Nice challenge btw!

Comment: I would perhaps add a test case that results in negative output(s) (e.g. `+=----=` resulting in `1 -3`) and perhaps one with multiple adjacent `==` (e.g. `--==` resulting in `-2 -2`). Apart from that I'd say it's good enough to be posted. And it may be simple, but it's good to have some simple challenges every now and then. :) In fact, I'd say it becomes harder and harder to come up with easy challenges suitable for beginners that aren't duplicates yet, so +1 from me. (I've already prepared a solution for when it goes to main.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen how about some of these?

Comment: @BowlingPizzaBall Looks good. 

Answer (score 3):

## How normal is this group?

Let \$(G, *)\$ be some [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)). That is, for all \$x, y, z \in G\$, the following axioms hold:

- \$x * y \in G\$
- \$x * (y * z) = (x * y) * z\$
- There exists some \$e \in G\$ such that \$x * e = e * x = x\$
- There exists some \$x^{-1} \in G\$ such that \$x * x^{-1} = x^{-1} * x = e\$

For some group \$(G, *)\$, we define a **subgroup** of this as a group \$(H, *)\$ for some subset \$H \subseteq G\$. The **trivial** subgroups of a group \$(G, *)\$ are when \$H = \{e\}\$ (the identity element of \$G\$) and when \$H = G\$.

For the sake of convenience, we will denote \$x * y\$ as \$xy\$. Let \$N\$ be a subgroup of \$G\$. We say that \$N\$ is **normal** if, for all \$g \in G\$ and \$x \in N\$, \$gxg^{-1} \in N\$. For any group, the trivial subgroups are normal, and so any group has at least 2 normal subgroups.

For example, let \$G = \{0,1,2,3\}\$ and \$x * y = x + y \bmod 4\$. The subgroups of \$G\$ are \$\{0\}\$, \$\{0, 2\}\$ and \$\{0,1,2,3\}\$, all of which are normal. Therefore, \$(G, *)\$ has 3 normal subgroups.

---

Given a finite group, output a positive integer \$n \ge 2\$ counting the number of normal subgroups of the input. You may take a group as input in any reasonable manner, including but not limited to:

- The set \$G\$ (as a set, list, etc.) along with a [black-box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706) \$* : G \times G \to G\$
- A square matrix representing the [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) of the group. You may choose whether to take \$G\$ as a separate input
- A collection of triples \$(a, b, c)\$ where \$a, b, c \in G\$ and \$c = a * b\$ (the order of such a triple is irrelevant, but must be consistent for all triples)
- etc.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

---

### Test cases

```
G
∗ : G×G → G
output

{0,1,2,3}
a*b = a+b mod 4
3
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CGCC Rocket Biking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251028/cgcc-rocket-biking)

Comment: Suggestion: Split it to two challenges (validating and generating instructions).

Comment: Good challenge! Just one question: what does _may not save the input while reading_ mean? Does "save" just mean saving to a file, or does it include variables too? In some languages, it would be impossible to do anything with input without saving it _somewhere_, even if not in an explicitly named variable.

Comment: @pajonk That's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I think the idea behind that could also be written as "The program may not work on more than one character of the input at any time.", i.e. reading the entire input bit-by-bit into a var and doing transformations on that isn't allowed. I used the wording from the file directly, which wasn't a good idea as it is rather lacking in other places too.

Comment: this does seem like an interesting challenge! I do think the while thing about only reading the input once is A) confusing and mostly unnecessary, and B) kinda against the [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/111305) against unobservable requirements. The code obviously takes a single text string in somehow, but what it does with that is not controllable. Also seconding the suggestion to split this into two challenges/get rid of one of them, as determining whether it is possible is a different matter from determining how to precisely stop at the end

Answer (score 3):

## Give me the electronic configuration.

As simple as the title.

Input will be a number denoting the atomic number.

The output will be the electronic configuration of the element of the given atomic number.

There are 2 rules for electronic configuration:

- The maximum number of electrons each shell can hold is given by \$2n^2\$ where n is the shell number starting from 1.
- The number each shell is allowed to hold from the last shell is given by \$2n^2\$ where n is the number starting from 2, in reverse.

You must fill each shell to it's limited capacity from left to right, with the remaining electrons on the last shell.

### Test cases

```
12 -> [2,8,2]
13 -> [2,8,3]
20 -> [2,8,8,2]
86 -> [2,8,18,32,18,8]
29 -> [2,8,18,1]
```

Comment: You may specify this a little more, as according to current spec any of `[2,2,8]`, `[2,8,1,1]`,`[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` is a valid answer for `12`.

Comment: @pajonk i added this line `You must fill each shell to it's limited capacity.`

Comment: 29 should return `[2,8,18,1]`, not `[2,8,18,2]`

Comment: BTW, it's more accurate to call it the electronic shell structure, not the electronic configuration

Comment: @Steffan that's how we learnt it

Comment: @PyGamer0 You must fill each shell to it's limited capacity **from left to right, with the remaining electrons on the last shell**, maybe? Remember, you're dealing with programmers here ;-)

Comment: @pajonk ok, edited.

Comment: If you look up the electronic configuration of atomic number 12, for example, you'll see things like `1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2` at the top. If you look up electron shells of atomic number 12, it will tell you 2,8,2.

Comment: I just noticed this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37657/electron-configurations

Answer (score 3):

## [Convert angle to clock time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246334/convert-angle-to-clock-time)

Comment: I strongly discourage strict output format restriction. Also, you may want to specify that only integer angles will be inputted (if that's the case).

Comment: @pajonk Is it okay now?

Comment: As long as `identifiable as clock times by humans` is also a list of hours and minutes and other reasonable formats - I'm fine with that :-)

Comment: Outputting `0:00` instead of `12:00` is invalid, right?

Comment: @Steffan Yes. The 12-hour time convention should be used.

Answer (score 3):

## [Derivative of a product](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246979/derivative-of-a-product)

Comment: Is the input always at least 2 characters long?

Comment: @pxeger Yes. (filler)

Answer (score 3):

## [Who needs 8 bits for one character?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246968/who-needs-8-bits-for-one-character)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the test cases in this challenge. Based on your description of how to get the solution, I wrote an (ungolfed) Python program that does that (as far as I know). However, my results differ greatly from yours, specifically in using `"the fox"` as input. For that string, you get `[170, 76, 19, ...]`, but my code gets `[172, 239, 134, ...]`. I'll put a TIO link in another comment, if you want to try it out. I do note that your first index (the index for `a` under "How, though?") starts at one, not zero. Could you help me understand this difference in results? Thanks!

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDbasMwDH33VwiXgkVC6NhLKPRLxiiOp7SCzDG2S5Ovz5Q43WYQiHPROTjM@T7692Xh7zDGDClH9jelbOfgAhqOSWZHG5sc83UYnxSdTaQUBxGxD49sUB0giCqbbs6UDIca9CP3rUZUHfu0ntOqHyM4sQCHswJ5LLiENey/aDIOq7cNFoeNs3CyGMYXdi1NBJfFFBE2kcJgHRl96rSk6l95guryz/ZXUShUg01ZLp22UryWitbfyLQ1DOSLqIYWS9GXl4UVY8mgiZzRWu@UzDEhCiCfttWp1isfq@HMn1hMey4vS74T9OP0Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online") Other than that problem, this sounds like a good challenge! +1

Comment: @SylvesterKruin It is one indexed because otherwise, `000` may get lost in leading zeros. Your Python code has a couple problems. One is that it does not pad leading zeros to the binary of each character. Another is that your code has a bug where it does not output the last byte  (because of Python exclusive ranges). Also, the last byte should pad zeros at the end, which it does not do.

Comment: Here is your code fixed: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDRasMwDEXf/RXCo9QiIbTbSyj0S8YIjue0Gq5tYoel@/lMTrpRg0G@vtI9KN7zNfi3ZaFbDGOGlEfyF/F43XS@CqF7A2eQsEt8H45GJ0PUufBtR6OTFYIim8jHKSsULxDZlVV/zzYpijXIKQ@tRBQ9@VTGSXHTc9dT7kyYfGappDXGklNr5cLlVTnrFecjVHDk5iGMYDgFKJ4E8CHu4/@G/KedlcHquMocosc7/3GhCP@0boNnnQu1mbAZbXTaWCUPvWRQic3PQK5QPPH9z0hQnZ9miZWJCtOo/cWqQw0FujixhhY3Tjtbo6SU21rK3SVEFnija3BVGt7pRFX70bivKWXV1rA/7BG3aKdTWRItS75aGML8Cw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, it didn't pad leading zeroes... that's what it was. I intentionally left out the last <8 bytes for reasons of simplicity. Thanks for the feedback! I'm looking forward to when this challenge is posted on the main site!

Answer (score 3):

## [King of the Cards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247462/king-of-the-cards)

Comment: This seems like it won't be particularly strategic

Answer (score 3):

## [Whyte Notation Translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247967/72535)

Comment: I think the scoring is sufficiently punishing to answers missing any cases that none will be able to make use of that in interesting ways.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms That's true, i guess i could change that to a multiplication instead. How about S = codesizefunc1 * (1+u) + codesizefunc2 * (1+v) ? Or maybe using the square root on u and v ?

Comment: Those might work too, but then you run into the risk of people optimizing the combination of code size and cases handled, and getting something boring like `x=>"AA20"`. I think it'd be better to just use the sum of the code sizes as the score. Since it seems like parsing the `o`s into indices into a list is probably going to be how most solutions work, and that's the interesting part of the challenge (since the outputs can't really be compressed), you might even consider allowing a third program that provides the list of names, that's weighted to count for less.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms What would be the purpose of the third program and the reduced weight of it ?

Comment: Since there's no interesting way to compress the list of names

Comment: `Prairie` and `Adriatic` are both mapped to `oOOOo`.

Comment: @Arnauld You're right, it's corrected and posted

Answer (score 3):



Answer (score 3):

## Find the winning Mormon Bridge card

Mormon Bridge (also called Oh Heck, similar to Oh H***) is a card game played (at least by me) with a standard Rook deck. A standard Rook deck includes cards 1-14 in 4 suits, which are black, red, green, and yellow, and a Rook card. Each round, a card is taken from the deck. It's suit is chosen as "trump." Then, players take turns playing cards. We'll call the suit of the first players card "sub-trump". If the Rook card is played, it wins. If trump was played, the highest trump card wins. Otherwise, the highest sub-trump card wins.

### Your Goal

Your goal is to take input for:

- Trump
- Sub-trump
- Cards played

and output the winning card. You may take input in any reasonable manner, swapping suit colors for numbers is fine, as is taking input for all cards played in order instead of separating the first card. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

(note that input can be taken in any reasonable format, these are written in a human-readable format.)

```
Trump: Red
Cards played: Red 4, Rook, Black 14, Yellow 7
Output: Rook

Trump: Green
Cards played: Red 14, Red 8, Green 2, Yellow 6
Output: Green 2

Trump: Yellow
Cards played: Red 5, Green 7, Red 12, Black 6
Output: Red 12
```

### Meta

What tags should be on this? Are the rules clear enough?

Comment: I think the rules are pretty clear. It would be great if you could add some examples of input => expected output

Comment: @mathjunkie added test cases

Answer (score 3):

## Tell me how many there are, in Polish

Today, you're going to be writing Polish. No, not Polish notation—*Polish*, the actual language spoken in Poland.

Given a number and a noun, output a Polish sentence telling me that there are that many of that thing, using the appropriate template below.

The input consists of an integer in the range from 0 to 200, and a string of 1 to 10 lowercase ASCII letters (called the "noun"). You may accept these inputs in any reasonable format.

The output must consist of one of the below output templates, where the number in the template (if any) has been replaced with the input integer, and the word `kot` in the template has been replaced with the input noun.

### Output templates

If the input number is 0, then use the output template

```
Nie ma żadnych kotów.
```

If the input number is 1, then use the output template

```
Jest 1 kot.
```

If the input number ends with 2, 3, or 4, but does **not** end with 12, 13, or 14, then use the output template

```
Są 4 koty.
```

In any other case, use the output template

```
Jest 8 kotów.
```

Note that the special characters used in these templates are:

- ż (in "żadnych") – U+017C Latin small letter Z with dot above
- ó (in the suffix "-ów") – U+00F3 Latin small letter O with acute
- ą (in "Są") – U+0105 Latin small letter A with ogonek

You may output these characters in any reasonably common character encoding (including HTML entities), and you may use combining characters instead of precomposed characters (or even a mixture of the two).

### Test cases

```
0 pomidor -> Nie ma żadnych pomidorów.
1 kwiat -> Jest 1 kwiat.
2 dom -> Są 2 domy.
5 wilk -> Jest 5 wilków.
13 komputer -> Jest 13 komputerów.
24 but -> Są 24 buty.
101 kurczak -> Jest 101 kurczaków.
```

### Do plurals in Polish really work that way?

No, the way it actually works is much more complicated.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in each language wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Suggested test-cases with 3-digit numbers ending with `02-04`, `12-14`, `x2-x4` (with `x>1`) and outside those ranges (`>101`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Is it a valid list?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248690/is-it-a-valid-list)

Comment: Suggestion: allow input also with `{}` or `()`, maybe even allow separators to be spaces or semicolons.

Comment: "Outputting by erroring/not erroring is *not* allowed" - I presume this is to prevent people from submitting solutions which are just `eval`. This [tends not be a good approach](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8943), and I think solutions like eval are still interesting. Maybe instead you could ask that people post solutions which don't directly do any parsing into one Community Wiki answer, like is sometimes done for builtin answers to catalogue-style questions. [contd...]

Comment: @pxeger Good idea :P

Comment: [...contd] But I think disallowing error output is not the right way to go about it, because (1) people will still post them, but wrapped in a try-catch or whatever, which is a no more interesting answer; and (2) people can write interesting answers which don't use `eval`, but which can be shorter using error output as a kind of "short-circuiting" output mechanism.

Comment: Suggested falsey test-case: `[[]][[]]`, which may erroneously be accepted by `eval`-like solutions

Comment: @pxeger Added..

Answer (score 3):

## [backwardS_hybriD-snakE_kebaB-cameL_case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248849/backwards-hybrid-snake-kebab-camel-case)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fix my FizzBuzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249186/fix-my-fizzbuzz)

Comment: You need some more test cases, to cover: inputs that are already valid and don't need shuffling, inputs with only numbers, inputs with no numbers, inputs with `FizzBuzz` in them.

Comment: @pxeger Done. (filler)

Answer (score 3):

## Change the Temperature of Swatchlings

### Warning: Contains Deltarune Chapter 2 Spoilers

### Summary

Your challenge today is to determine the minimum number of turns needed to
change the temperatures of an arbitrary amount of Swatchlings to all be the same.

### Context

In the second chapter of [Deltarune](https://deltarune.com/), there are enemies you encounter that are called [Swatchlings](https://deltarune.fandom.com/wiki/Swatchling) (suit-wearing butler-like characters that serve the main antagonist of the chapter). These enemies always appear in battle in groups with at least one outlier in terms of suit color<sup>[source](https://deltarune.fandom.com/wiki/Swatchling#Strategy)</sup>. Swatchlings are defeated by making *all* Swatchlings in the group have the same suit colour.

Each Swatchling's color can be changed in stages, either becoming warmer (redder) or colder (bluer). While there are only five colours in the actual game, for this challenge, there will be an infinite amount, represented by positive integers.

During each turn of a battle, there are 3 ways to change the temperature of a
Swatchling: increasing/decreasing the temperature by 2 stages, increasing the temperature by 1 stage or decreasing the temperature by 1 stage. You may perform up to 3 of these actions per turn, and no action twice in a turn.

### Task and Worked Example

Given a list of Swatchling temperatures, determine the minimal number of turns needed to change the temperatures of all Swatchlings to be the same. Note that

For example, given the following temperatures:

```
[1, 5, 5]
```

The optimal solution would be:

```
Turn 1:
Increase Swatchling #1 by 2 stages: [3, 5, 5]

Turn 2:
Increase Swatchling #1 by 2 stages: [5, 5, 5]
```

Meaning a minimum of 2 turns are needed to change the temperatures of all Swatchlings to be the same.

Another example is:

```
[1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

One optimal solution might be:

```
Turn 1:
Increase Swatchling #1 by 2 stages: [3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
Decrease Swatchling #4 by 1 stage: [3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1]
Increase Swatchling #6 by 1 stage: [3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1]

Turn 2:
Decrease Swatchling #2 by 2 stages: [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1]
Decrease Swatchling #5 by 1 stage: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]

Turn 3:
Increase Swatchling #7 by 2 stages: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Meaning a minimum of 2 turns are needed to change the temperatures of all Swatchlings to be the same.

### Rules

- Input will be a list of positive integers representing the temperatures of each Swatchling. The list will contain at least one Swatchling.
- Output will be an integer representing the minimum number of turns needed to change the temperatures of all Swatchlings to be the same.

### Test Cases

```
[1, 5, 5] => 2
[1, 2, 5] => 1
[1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1] => 3
[1, 7] => 2
[1, 10, 3] => 4
```

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the aim of the game is to get y'all's byte count as
low as possible, just like the turn count to make all the Swatchlings the same
temperature.

### Sandbox Meta

- Is the explanation clear enough?

Comment: For your first case, can't you decrease #3 by 2, decrease it by 1 again, and increase #1 by 1?

Comment: @emanresuA huh, so you can. Just tested it in deltarune lol

Comment: I'm assuming the line after the solution for `[1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1]` should say "Meaning a minimum of **3** turns are needed..."

Comment: Is `[2,5,5]` 1 or 2, or say is multiple operating on one item allowed in one turn?

Comment: `[1, 10, 3]` should be 3 if I understand it correctly. `[1, 10, 3] => [3, 8, 4] => [5, 6, 4] => [5, 5, 5]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Simplify Rubik's Cube Moves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249787/simplify-rubiks-cube-moves)

Answer (score 3):

## Infinite quote escaping sequence

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250015/infinite-quote-escaping-sequence)

Comment: "one of these sequences" - does this include the infinite string `aa'a'a'...`? Or do we have to output one of the numeric sequences?

Comment: @pxeger one of the numeric sequences

Comment: What does "connect the original string" mean?

Comment: @mousetail I edited it - it should be concatenate

Comment: I feel like the sentence is still confusing. I'm confused by the exact order. First the original string, then a "a", then the string surrounded by quotes right?

Comment: @mousetail Yes. How should I phrase this? Is this better?

Comment: Maybe include a example what it would look like after 1 or 2 iterations

Comment: I don't understand the first step of the process. From the examples it just looks like you are doing the second step over and over.  If I try to do it with the first step I just get an infinite sequence of `'`s.

Comment: I rewrote the process as an algorithm in pseudocode. Is it clearer now?

Comment: A worked out example of generating one of the iterations would be helpful. `aa'a'a'aa''a'''` is right about where you lose me, I'd like to see that one step-by-step

Comment: It is now clearer, but I, at least, would prefer if you just described it in a normal way rather than using pseudocode.

Comment: @WheatWizard I tried rewriting it. Is this clear?

Comment: The commas helped a lot. I get it now :-) I still think a worked out example would be nice, but this is definitely easier to parse with the commas

Comment: May I swap 0/1 for sequence 1? (Use 1 for non-quote, 0 for quote)

Comment: @tsh yes, I edited that in

Answer (score 3):

## [Runs of Ones (What Fun!)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250365/runs-of-ones-what-fun)

Comment: Not sure if only on my browser: Width of ✓ and number are different. So last ✓ is under `]` instead of `9`.

Comment: Apparently, the monospace font doesn't include Unicode characters, oh well

Answer (score 3):

## [Remove redundant parenthesis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250596/remove-redundant-parenthesis)

Comment: Tags: [tag:balanced-string], [tag:string]

Comment: If there never will be an empty pair, you probably shouldn't give `(abc((123))())` as an example.

Answer (score 3):

## [Shifted auto-sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250338/shifted-auto-sum)

Answer (score 3):

## [Solve a jigsaw puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251837/solve-a-jigsaw-puzzle)

Comment: I am always in favour of loose I/O criteria, so I'd definitely include the first three dots and also leave up to answerers the value fir edges (not restricting to numbers, some may use `NA` or `Inf`, or even `"a"`, but I'd keep it consistent). Anyway, I suggest placing the example between paragraphs 2 and 3 (so that I/O rules are after the example). Also, you may want to specify what to do with multiple solutions (if such inputs are possible).

Comment: I have I feeling that I saw a challenge like this before, but I cannot find it. So maybe there isn't one.

Comment: @pajonk I think this counts as a duplicate: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/solving-a-jigsaw-puzzle

Answer (score 3):

[Polyglot Quiz (Cops' thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251450/polyglot-quiz-cops-thread) [Polyglot Quiz (Robber's thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251451/polyglot-quiz-robbers-thread)

Comment: Not a comment on the challenge itself, but I like the four-state CnR system!

Comment: Does the cop reveal which of the 4 programs satisfy which of the criteria 1-4?

Comment: @pajonk Yes they should.  I'll edit it to make it clear.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I have a feeling this is equivalent to "standard" CnR, where to become safe you need to reveal your language (or other features the challenge is about) - or are there some differences I missed?

Comment: @pajonk In a normal CnR if a robber ever gets your answer you cannot score. However here your answer is cracked after 10 days you still get to score your answer. On a lot of CnR's people will delay the reveal to give robbers an extra chance,  this ruleset allows you to do that without having to sacrifice your score.

Comment: @WheatWizard I get it now, thanks! This indeed makes more sense.

Comment: Requiring that languages can run on FreeBSD seems unnecessarily restrictive to me, it being a pretty niche OS in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @pxeger The idea is that if it is Free, and runs on both linux and freeBSD it is very likely to run everywhere.  And users should be able to sandbox either linux or freeBSD.  It also doesn't seem like a very high bar to cross actually.  If you can find a language that can't be run on freeBSD but has otherwise wide support that would make a compelling case.

Answer (score 3):

## [A better Hexagony template](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251002/78410)

Comment: 4000th answer to this question, hooray

Comment: "_For convenience, define \$a(0)=0\$ (for zero-sized grid)._" \$a(0)=3\times0(0−1)+1=1\$ though. Does the \$n=1\$ output have to be `*`, or are we allowed to output `.` instead as well? In terms of output it doesn't really make sense, but for the formula it does (and it would save me 2 bytes in my prepared solution ).

Comment: @Kevin I meant size 0 grid has zero spots and size 1 has one, but now that I think of it, I don't know if Hexagony interpreter special-cases empty code or it just treats it as size 1. Something to think about...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I decided to allow both :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Simplify a Cycle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256920/simplify-a-cycle)

Comment: A worked out example would be great. I don't get why aren't all vertices from the input in the output.

Comment: Is this really "given a path that may include cycles, remove the cycles"?

Comment: @UnrelatedString no, it's "given a cycle between two vertices, return the shortest cycle"

Comment: The last test case seems to contradict that, since the shortest cycle between 1 and 7 seems like it should just be `[1,2,7]`. I guess what I'm getting at is there needs to be a clearer spec and/or worked through example :P

Comment: So is this a 1-D graph or what? Are you only giving us the X coordinates or what? Or am I just not understanding a thing? If we have the coordinates (both X and Y) is this basically removing adjacent coordinates that are colinear?

Comment: @Steffan these numbers arent coordinates; they're just the labels on the nodes of the graph. the input is a path that exists on the graph, meaning you can get from each node in the list to the next node in the list by following a single edge

Comment: Maybe an example program will help.

Comment: [Questions for @lyxal .](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61870888#61870888)

Comment: Suppose his answers are what I expect, [this](https://tio.run/##ZVLBagIxEL3vVwx40IVUUGsVwUPbQ@mllxZ6WKTE3Vk34CYhmdXu19tJoi3aQJLJy7x5j0lsT43Rs9NpAI8dh24Fb127RQdP0jfosqzCGrxq7V7V/VfZl3scxTVfwQCeQwTKg9QgnZP9OAMew@Ew7u@Jp5ATILJg24PD1hyU3oGVjjxQIwk8ccxVKkCeR0UN4whetggHdITf15X9pXKVPMEaik0Wr46N4nNEg8XPeAzFyotZbQiwtdSLSAgjaaxjytgaO8qZ@sGkvfR05SAMVZ8hUPpP6bUOMi71A3y3vYtXfyJhRCjpFKskp3SF36NUMN/AVfoAXpCi@z3W1Bo2Y8qyc6hLBBMFz1ZuaZ10UhNiBWSgZo1UxegdcpFfd7@0246OpbX8FhdfXPLNQCuJ@G8c@cnGqdsOqXP6HzvLTrVx3B7bUWhSkRUTMRUzcc/rfCOy4p4PDxFaijnvS7EI8ERwXgqmYnGes8vdVARaWOdixtBmFU1YpzSNopi4/awRzfPTDw) should work.

Comment: It was at 4 char left. Sorry for another post. Why must [1,2,7,2,7,2,3,7] be [1,2,3,7] ([1,2,...,3,7]) and not [1,2,7] ([1,2,7,...])?

Comment: The mathematical definition deems that both are correct. You might want to clarify or add that to the test case.

Comment: [E](https://tio.run/##ZVJBT@swDL73V1jaYasUJm1jD1SJA3BAXLi8J3GoqqesdWmkNgmJy@ivH06ygTYiJXHsfP4@O7ETdUZvDocZ3I9sugJexmGHDh6k79BlWYMteDXYXrXT/3qqe1zENS9gBo/BAuVBapDOyWmZAY/5fB73vwmnkC9ARMFuAoeD@VD6Dax05IE6SeCJbc7SAPLcK@rYj@DlgPCBjvDzPHNMdhfXsiiuVhWLufewR8b2PewQRh8oltbYRQ7voyIE0xLqlMeflDWpJriDsspiaN8pPkdvKPE1HoOY@lSsNgQ4WJpEBISRNCZBR84Z/GNQLz2dVRCGao8uUPqH6bkNNC71E/y4u4qhH5JfhSc6pRv8XKSEeQVn12fwhBTV99jSYFiMqevRoa5DP2IkIS9ho3RSE2IDZKBljpTF6DfkJN/qvmGXHV1Ka/ktT7o45YuBQRLx39rzky9Ttx3S6PQvdJYdWuO4PXak0KQyK1diLTbimtdtJbLymg9/outWbHm/FTfBvRJ8LxlrcXOcm1NsLQIsrFuxYVdVRBHWKU2LSCYuP3v05vnhCw)

Comment: ...dited to match the test cases. The last post was too long.

Answer (score 3):

## Quantise a list [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

In music production, quantisation is the process of "aligning" recorded notes to the beat, to remove the variability caused by imprecise human playing.

In this challenge, we will implement an abstract and approximate version of quantisation, representing notes as runs of positive integers, and using zeroes to represent gaps. The "beat" will be defined as every second note, starting with the first (even indices, 0-based).

Given a list of non-negative integers, insert or remove zeroes such that every run of non-zeroes begins on an even index (using 0-based indexing).

Runs of non-zeroes may not be split or joined together if they weren't already in the input. In other words, a zero cannot be inserted or removed if it only has non-zeroes next to it.

The minimal number of insertion/removal operations must be performed. If a removal is possible, it should be preferred over an insertion.

### Test cases

todo

blah blah code golf rules

Comment: Removal of double negatives: "No runs of non-zeroes may be split..." -> "Runs of non-zeroes may not be split...", maybe also "...zero cannot be inserted or removed if it only has non-zeroes..." -> "...zero can only be inserted or removed if it has at least one zero..."

Comment: The latter conversion is incorrect, because `[0, 3, 4]` can become `[3, 4]` because the zero has an end-of-the-list next to it rather than a zero. I agree this could be clearer though

Comment: that's not supported by the current phrasing either: "a zero cannot be inserted or removed if it only has non-zeroes next to it". If that zero can be removed, you're saying it has something other than non-zeros next to it, which means you're saying that either "end-of-the-list"s or 3s are zero. Addendum: my head hurts

Comment: @thejonymyster My head hurts too and now you see why lol. The way I drafted this in my head is slightly different from how I wrote it down, which doesn't help

Comment: Maybe instead of splitting / joining runs, just say the number of runs of nonzeros cant change between input and output. That handles the 0s on the ends situations too and is probably simpler

Comment: I mean, the first sentence (before "in other words") explains it pretty well already. Maybe I should just remove the second rephrasing.

Answer (score 3):

## Zip two arrays

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a list of arrays of the same dimension, zip them at the lowest level. That is, you should output an array of the same dimension, for which the value at each index is a list of the corresponding elements in the input arrays.

For example, for two 3x3 arrays

```
[[123]  [[abc]    [[[1a][2b][3c]]
 [456] , [def]  →  [[4d][5e][6f]]
 [789]]  [ghi]]    [[7g][8h][9i]]]
```

and for the three 4x4 arrays

```
[[19  47  4   69 ]  [[103 67  17  28 ]  [[7   9   48  204]
 [156 120 54  104]   [167 80  99  62 ]   [26  125 230 212]
 [30  70  212 96 ] , [102 165 246 192] , [61  118 137 101]
 [62  80  152 205]]  [118 193 222 65 ]]  [125 247 209 31 ]]
 ↓
[[[19  103 7  ] [47  67  9  ] [4   17  48 ] [69  28  204]]
 [[156 167 26 ] [120 80  125] [54  99  230] [104 62  212]]
 [[30  102 61 ] [70  165 118] [212 246 137] [96  192 101]]
 [[62  118 125] [80  193 247] [152 222 209] [205 65  31 ]]]
```

### Test cases

todo

### Sandbox notes

- This feels like something that should've already been posted.
- Name/wording suggestions?

Comment: To me, it makes more sense to say "Zip arrays at the lowest level" or "Transpose array at the lowest level" or "Multi-dimensional transpose" instead of "Combine"

Comment: It is one special case of [APL dyadic transpose (challenge)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/176164/78410), and precisely [BQN transpose](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=YeKGkFsKIFsxOeKAvzQ34oC/NOKAvzY5LCAxNTbigL8xMjDigL81NOKAvzEwNCwgMzDigL83MOKAvzIxMuKAvzk2LCA2MuKAvzgw4oC/MTUy4oC/MjA1XSwKIFsxMDPigL82N+KAvzE34oC/MjgsIDE2N+KAvzgw4oC/OTnigL82MiwgMTAy4oC/MTY14oC/MjQ24oC/MTkyLCAxMTjigL8xOTPigL8yMjLigL82NV0sCiBbN+KAvznigL80OOKAvzIwNCwgMjbigL8xMjXigL8yMzDigL8yMTIsIDYx4oC/MTE44oC/MTM34oC/MTAxLCAxMjXigL8yNDfigL8yMDnigL8zMV1dCuKAolNob3cgYQrijYlh).

Comment: @Bubbler [Indeed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61905541#61905541) ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Erasure Poetry

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Given two strings of digits \$A\$ and \$B\$, count the minimum number of digits that need to be removed from \$A\$ to make it a substring of \$B\$. (META: i am still brainstorming what this actual challenge part should be, though i think this challenge might be good).

However, you will not be "writing" programs/functions to solve this challenge, so much as you will be finding them in the previous answer.

### Challenge specification

(spec in progress)

Take two strings of digits \$A\$ and \$B\$. You can assume these strings will both be nonzero in length and contain any amount of the following characters in any order: `0123456789`. Return the number of digits needed to be removed from \$A\$ in order to make it be a substring of \$B\$.

Worked out examples:

```
A: "3"
B: "123"
Output: 0
Explanation: "3" is already a substring of "123", so 0 characters need to be removed from it

A: "1322"
B: "12345"
Output: 2
Explanation: "12" is the biggest potential substring of B that could be made from A, and it requires removing the 3 and one of the 2s

A: "12345"
B: "123"
Output: 2
Explanation: "123" is the biggest potential substring of B that could be made from A, and it requires removing the 4 and 5

A: "12345"
B: "67890"
Output: 5
Explanation: None of A exists in B, so "" (the empty string) is the biggest potential substring of B that could be made from A, and it requires removing all 5 of the digits
```

### Scoring specification

Contrary to what I said in the intro, you will technically be writing a program or function to solve this challenge. However, you will not be scored directly on your code length.

Included with your answer will be a list of characters you will remove from the previous answer's code such that it becomes your answer's code. If this is not possible with removals alone, you may also add characters to the previous answer, but this will come with a score penalty.

In particular: Your score is the number of characters you need to add to some substring of the previous answer's code in order to make it your answer's code. Lowest score wins.

The first answer to base your score off of will be provided at the bottom of this post.

### Answer chaining rules

Importantly, you may not answer the challenge in a language that has already been used unless your answer has a lower score. Flags and version numbers do not differentiate languages in this challenge.

(more clarifications and guidelines)

### Answer chaining example

## 6. [MyOwnLanguage](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/107310), +3 characters

previous answer with removed characters replaced with `*`:

```
do ****thing *o**
```

with my added characters becomes:

```
do thing now!
```

[Try It Online](https://www.google.com/)

## 7. [HQ9+2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Galaxy), +0 characters

previous answer with removed characters replaced with `*`:

```
do*thing****!
```

with my (0) added characters becomes:

```
dothing!
```

[Try It Online](https://www.bing.com/)

### Starting answer

## 0. [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), +361 characters

```javascript
f = (a, b) => {
  const isSubstring = (c, d) => {
    if(!c){
      return true
    }else{
      return RegExp(`${c}`).test(d)
    }
  }
  if(isSubstring(a, b)){
    return 0
  }else{
    a = [...Array(a.length).keys()]
        .map(w => a.slice(0, w)
                + a.slice(w + 1)
            )
    a = a.map(w => f(w,b))
    return 1 + Math.min(...a)
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNTsMwEITveYol4uAVwcoPhXIIEgeOXOCIkOq6TmpIQ2Q7DVWVZw9OnYYEYcnyyvPt7NgfbM80V7Iy1/tl12WQAmEBrBHSBzh6APyr1Aakfq3X2ihZ5j3BA9iMBIDMyAVHVwMoYWpVglG1ON20otDij/gi8qfviqwuj7xdITVCG7JBh3tuW9PJVBdqmDGYhN7MnNlkb5TSR6XYgTBaiDI3W6Sf4qAJvg8BAOiOVaTp0zOqC8kFCQNocNTP62rUG1tHcwDHkezXLyNNYENOM0a29ZmZLd3JkthwDE/Pa7vKvsoQ23Ky8xM/6I8oTnz7sSmE6E0IP0ri2BK9frNwRDwlBmHu8T/h394t70NHLLD7AQ)

## meta

work in progresss, but feel free to suggest anything you think i might be missing, even if it seems obvious. Still working out the formatting for everything to look nice :-)

Comment: How does this work with SBCS?

Comment: @CommandMaster not sure yet, im thinking about just making it based on the byte value itself. seems fair since most languages use just printable ascii, and from what ive seen, most SCBSes have their printable ascii on the same bytes as regular printable ascii. I might require / ask that languages with alternate encodings provide a hex dump. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @CommandMaster actually I changed my mind, im making it char based so its just gonna be easier to work with in general :P I can't imagine there will be much cheesing in the way of "my language has one million different encodings for these commands so i can do every solution in 0", plus you can only use the language again if you can actually lower its score :P this should be ok :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Compute the Fabius function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/252009)

- \$f(x)\$ always takes on rational values at dyadic rationals (i.e. \$\frac m{2^n}\$ with \$m,n\in\mathbb Z\$). It could also be interesting to restrict input to such values, and ask for a rational output.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is it even possible to exactly determine the value of the function for any given input \$x\$?

Comment: @97.100.97.109 What do you mean by "exactly"? There do exist algorithms which can approximate the value of \$f\$ to arbitrary precision for any given input. For example, [from math se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218832/how-to-compute-the-values-of-this-function-fabius-function)

Comment: I suppose the answer to my question is "no" (when the input is not a dyadic rational). In that case, how do solvers decide the level of precision with which to calculate the answer? I think that limiting to dyadic rationals is a good idea because then there is [an explicit formula to calculate the values](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2135800/1073925).

Comment: @97.100.97.109 I don't think the absence of an explicit, non-limiting formula should be a factor in that decision. How would you "exactly" calculate \$\sin\$ for arbitrary inputs?

Comment: I think it can make two challenges actually: first with `f` on dyadic rationals asking for rational output (no floating point errors); second with `f` at any input with stated required precision (maybe limited to interval 0-1).

Comment: I'd prefer keeping the function to `[0,1]` where it is defined by the cumulative distribution.

Answer (score 3):

## Convert integer to IEEE 754 float

The task is simple, given a 32 bit integer, convert it to its floating point value as defined by the IEEE 754 (32-bit) standard.

### IEEE 754

[*Here is a converter for your reference.*](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Here is how the format looks:
[image]

The standard is similar to scientific notation.

The sign bit determines whether the output is negative or positive. If the bit is set, the number is negative otherwise it is positive.

The exponent bit determines the exponent (base 2), it's value is offset by 127. Therefore the exponent is \$2^{n-127}\$ where n is the integer representation of the exponent bits.

The mantissa defines a floating point number in the range \$[1,2)\$. The way it represents the number is like binary, the most significant bit is \$\frac 1 2\$, the one to the right is \$\frac 1 4\$, the next one is \$\frac 1 8\$ and so on... A one by default is added to the value.

Now the final number is: $$\text{sign}\cdot 2^{\text{exponent}-127}\cdot \text{mantissa}$$

### Test cases

```
1078523331 ->   3.1400001049041748046875
1076719780 ->   2.71000003814697265625
1036831949 ->   0.100000001490116119384765625
3264511895 -> -74.24919891357421875
1056964608 ->   0.5
3205496832 ->  -0.5625
```

For this challenge assume that cases like `NaN` and `inf` are not going to be the inputs, and subnormals need not be handled, and you may output `0` for the case where the number represented is `-0`.

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/160934/78410). Kinda opposite task, but I think there are certainly overlapping techniques around reinterpreting a bit pattern from one type to another.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this challenge is asking for. Are we supposed to reinterpret the integer as a float?

Comment: @pigrammer yes.

Comment: @solid.py shouldn't all the digits be accurate, because there is no floating point conversion error when you are reinterpreting an integer as a *float*

Comment: @solid.py `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...` should be accurately stored, because, well it can be accurately represented by IEEE754, which is supported by most languages...

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexadecimal -> Binary Art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252379/hexadecimal-binary-art/252380)

Comment: Is `10000001` actually 81? A simple web search shows 81 is `1010001`

Comment: -1 because of that

Comment: @py3programmer Since hexadecimal is in base sixteen, hexadecimal 81 is `10000001`.

Comment: @py3programmer no. Hexadecimal is base 16. I've edited the post so you can remove your downvote.

Comment: There's a different way to calculate binary numbers in base 16? I didn't know that.

Comment: @py3programmer `81` in base 16 isn't the same as `81` in base 10, the same way that, e.g. `10` in binary is not equal to `10` in decimal. `81` in base 16 is 8*16+1 = 129 in decimal, which is indeed `10000001` in binary.

Comment: Since 16 is a power of 2, you can also convert each character individually into binary then concatenate -- `8` -> `1000`, `1` -> `0001`, `81` -> `10000001`.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. I was think more in Python terms, `bin(81)` instead of `bin(0x81)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Find a word in the dictionary of all possible words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252652/find-a-word-in-the-dictionary-of-all-possible-words)

Comment: Can input use strings? (e.g. 123 and 231 for your example)

Comment: @pigrammer that's a [default input method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/97691) and thus should be fune

Comment: @solid.py that should be fine so long as tuples of arbitrary length can be handled

Answer (score 3):

## Generate QR code from string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-matrix)

I'm surprised to have not seen anyone doing this particular challenge yet.

The challenge is simple: Take input as a string, your task is to turn it into a QR code.

This challenege originally requires outputting to an image (or any graphical output), but to relax the restrictions down, you only need to output the result as a matrix (or a 2D array). A binary string (with splits between) is also acceptable.

And for sake of simplicity, you will only need to output a 25x25 QR code image (which is the most popular QR code size, I believe). For the input `Version 2`, the image should look like this:

[image: Version 2 QR code on Wikipedia]

You may not need to handle empty strings.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

### More resources

- [QR Code on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)
- [Reed–Solomon error correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction)

Comment: Can we output as a binary string

Comment: @py3programmer No, the output string must be full, correct image data. If you are using a binary string to later be used with metadata to output to a, say bitmap file, then yes, you can.

Comment: You may consider turning this into a [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/binary-matrix/info) challenge instead. It would be easier to test on TIO and the like.

Comment: Also, it would need to be significantly more specified. Which version of QR code? Which kind of data? With which error correction level? (Challenges are supposed to be self-contained. So, ideally, the full algorithm should be explained.)

Comment: @oeuf I meant a binary string that describes whether each pixel is lighted up or not. The binary string would describe the pixels from left to right. Is that valid?

Comment: @py3programmer Perhaps yes. I will take some time to think about this.

Comment: @Arnauld I have edited to relax the output restrictions down and specify more about the output. Thanks for suggestion! I am currently deciding on the error correction level

Comment: Don't we need 2 inputs? One for the version, and one for the string we need to encode the qr code with?

Comment: @py3programmer No, we only need one input for the string.

Comment: So you mean that using version 2, you'll encode the input as a QR code?

Comment: @py3programmer Yes.

Comment: Can one use built-in libraries that generate QR codes? I think that the real would be to compute the image/matrix

Comment: @matteo_c Builtins are allowed, but builtins that solves the entire problem are generally disencouraged.

Answer (score 3):

## [Does the sequence shut the box?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253127/does-the-sequence-shut-the-box)

Comment: small nitpicks: "roles" should be "rolls", "d6 dice" is redundant and should probably just be "six sided dice", and `[]` input is an edge case, and i think we should probably be able to assume input wont be empty.

Comment: actual feedback: cool challenge idea :-) a worked out example of how a specific sequence could be used to shut the box would be very helpful in allowing everyone to understand the challenge more

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I cleaned those things up and added the example. Personally I like the inclusion of the `[]` input as it adds more thinking to the golfing (can one save bytes by formulating the general case to include the edge case). But I admit it may be weird to say "not playing the game is not a winning sequence".

Comment: ultimately up to you :-) thanks for humoring me :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Triangular polkadot numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253309/78410)

Answer (score 3):

## Integer Bluffing (Still a draft)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

It's an exciting night at the IGS casino, as a brand new table game is being revealed - Integer Bluffing. Bots from all over the network have come to have a chance at playing the inaugral game, and luckily for you, you just happen to have a seat at the table.

### The Rules of Integer Bluffing

At the beginning of a game of Integer Bluffing, each player starts with 20 tokens. A round of Integer Bluffing consists of 4 phases: (i) the deal, (ii) declaring, (iii) reacting, (iv) the showdown

#### The Deal

Each round, 1 player is chosen to pay an ante, which increases during the game, into the pot. A random integer in the range [1, 8] is then "dealt" to each player. Players only know the true value of their own integer, and once an integer is given to a player, it can't be dealt to anyone else.

#### Declaring

Starting with the player after the player who paid the ante, each player has the choice to either: a) decline to play the round (fold) or b) put 1 token into the pot and declare what their integer is (play).

Here's the twist - if choosing to play, the player doesn't have to tell the truth about the value of their integer - they can lie and declare they have an integer they don't have. The player also sets a flag whether they say they are bluffing or not - this can also be lied about.

Consider the following game with players A, B, C and D:

| Player | Integer |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 7 |
| D | 3 |

Assuming Player A paid the ante for the round, player B goes first in the declaring round. Player B sees that they have a `2`, which is highly unlikely to win against other integers, so they fold.

Player C sees that they have a `7`, so they choose to play the round. Wanting to trick Players D and A into putting a token into the pot, C declares that they have `2`, and states they are not bluffing.

Player D sees that Player C allegedly has `2` and that they aren't bluffing. Player D knows that `3` is higher than `2`, but knows that Player A might have a higher integer. Therefore, Player D decides to declare `6`, not bluffing, in the hopes that Player A folds.

TODO: Continue writing

Comment: "new table game"? Pfff, I've played this before :3

Comment: You should state the number of players at the table (always exactly 4?), probably in the "The Rules of Integer Bluffing". I also think this sentence: "The player also sets a flag whether they say they are bluffing or not" should be reworded. I think "The player may also set a flag to say they are bluffing" works.

Answer (score 3):

## [Tic, Tac, stub your Toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253782/tic-tac-stub-your-toe)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and thanks for using the Sandbox! Currently, this is missing a winning criterion. If it's [tag:code-golf], you should probably specify.

Comment: I'd also recommend allowing looser I/O formats - [see here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). It's your challenge though, so if you really want to keep the strict formats, that's okay.

Comment: Don't know how to add tags to specify which type so right now it's just fastest possible solution wins. Also will update to remove number of testcases and commas from input.

Answer (score 3):

## Is this series of quotes valid python? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Python string parsing has quite a few edge cases. This is a string:

```
"a"
```

Putting 2 strings immediately after each other implicitly concatenates them, so this is also a string:

```
"a""a"
```

However, if you put 3 quotes in a row, it will create a "triple quoted string" which can only be ended by another triple quoted string. A triple quoted string can contain other quotes. These quotes will not end the string unless there are 3 of them. Thus this is valid:

```
"""a"a"""
```

Of course, you can combine these together, so this is a valid string:

```
"""a""""a"
```

And this:

```
"""""aaa"""""""""
```

A string is *not* valid if:

1. Any `a` appears outside of a string literal (would get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in python) OR
2. The end of the sequence is inside a string literal (would get `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)` in python)

### Your task

Given a string containing 2 distinct characters, one representing a double quote and another representing any alphanumeric character, determine if it would be a valid python string, or invalid syntax.

You do not need to consider single quotes or how double and single quotes normally interact.

A array of booleans or a array of bytes would also be a valid input method.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins.

### Test Cases

| Truthy | Falsy |
| --- | --- |
| `"a"` (1-1) | `"a` (1) |
| `"a""a"` (1-2-1) | `"a"a"` (1-1-1) |
| `"""a"a"""` (3-1-3) | `""a"a"""` (2-1-3) |
| `"""a""""a"` (3-4-1) | `"""a"""a"` (3-3-1) |
| `"""""aaa"""""""""` (5-9) | `"""""aaa""""""""` (5-8) |
| `""""""""""""` (12) | `""""""aaa"""""""""` (6-8) |
| `"a""a""a""a"` (1-2-2-2-1) | `""""` (4) |
| `"a"""` (1-3) |  |

`eval` or `exec` or `ast.literal_eval` would be [valid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17718/91213) answers, though I hope to see more creative python answers as well.

Comment: Well, well, well... `exec` can be used, so I'm claiming that. Ha!

Comment: Ok go for it. Not sure if I would count that as creative though

Comment: But the problem with this is, `lambda`s are not going to work in Python, and neither can normal functions. LHS = `SyntaxError` = RHS -> hence proved that `eval` and `exec` 4 byters are not valid.

Comment: And neither will normal inputs. Therefore, python would not work at all for this program, as input cannot only be provided.

Comment: Of course python works? You can take input as a string containing quotes

Comment: Though I assume it could be made to work in online interpreters like TIO and ATO, but not in IDLE style.

Comment: "string containing quotes": won't the string itself contain quotes? Like `"a"a"` when passed to an argument would be `'"a"a"'`

Comment: Notice the `'`?

Comment: The string will contain only double quotes.

Comment: *Nod nod* so when are you posting this?

Comment: When I get 3-4 votes

Comment: +1. You're 2 votes away :P

Comment: Hey why'd you claim `exec`?

Comment: Because it's boring. Note that duplicate answers are technically allowed but don't expect any votes

Comment: But it wasn't your idea to use it... I had to rack my brain for a minute to figure out an alternative approach :(

Comment: I consider it equivalent to eval, it's basically the same thing.

Comment: It's not. `eval` is only for expressions, while `exec` is for more than that.

Comment: In this case all values, valid or invalid, are expressions.

Comment: I don't mind; I'm still posting the `exec` answer when the challenge is released, but I probably will also add a C one.

Comment: But if people say "it was already claimed" I'm going to reference the earlier message that allowed you to let me go for it

Comment: Yea sure but don't expect any votes for that

Comment: I'm not, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## [50 digits of π in HQ0-9+-INCOMPUTABLE?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254546/78410)

Comment: Sorry few questions: are those the *only* commands avaiable? How would I append to the buffer then if I didn't want to use `q`/`Q`?

Comment: @DialFrost 1) Yes. 2) It's your job to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

## Base Neutral Numbering System [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

Comment: Can we output as a nested list? Like `<<1> * <<1>>>` = `[[[1],[[1]]]]`

Comment: Also, can we omit the `*`? Most of the test cases omit it, only the last two use it.

Comment: Omitting the * from the test cases was a mistake. I think `[[[1],[[1]]]]` already qualifies by my rules since I allow replacing `<>` with `[]` and `*` with `, `.

Answer (score 3):

## [Totally random Catan number distributions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255009/110698)

Answer (score 3):

## [Turn two dice into one die](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255460/113442)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that target is divisible by die1 * die2? Seems all your test cases assume so

Comment: What if there are multiple possibilities? Or will the input configuration guarantee an unique solution?

Comment: @mousetail that issue is already addressed in the assumptions: "assume N is a divisor of A*B"

Comment: @pajonk if there are multiple solutions (such as making a one-sided), you only need to return one of them. I will clarify that in the post. I have not proven mathematically if there are unique solutions for the examples in the post, but I will postulate that they are (up to permutation)

Answer (score 3):

## KotH: Build an Organism

A while back, I made a thing that simulates a world, with a bunch of organisms with randomly chosen genes:

[image: dieplife]

These would code for things like how the organism would manage resources (such as sugar, water, and starch), whether it could photosynthesize, hunt, run away from enemies, or defend itself using tough materials like wood or stone spikes.

In this challenge, you'll design an organism which can effectively survive. This could be through strategies including:

- Being an effective hunter, chasing down and killing prey
- Being difficult to attack, such as by having tough armor and fleeing from stronger organisms
- Growing and dividing too quickly for it to be possible that all organisms of your species are killed at the same time

I will update this post with a spec listing all available resources, materials, genetic traits, and actions later.

Comment: this seems fun.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rotate an Image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/rotate-an-image)

Comment: Might want to clarify if [exif-orientations](https://zpl.fi/exif-orientation-in-different-formats/) are allowed

Answer (score 3):

## Change the subject [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256828/change-the-subject)

Comment: Nice challenge! Is it guaranteed that there will be an order in which each sentence connects to the next?

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes, I'll add that to the challenge rules

Comment: How are words defined in a sentence? Space separated or any non-letter/punctuation separated?

Comment: @lyxal, to not make things too complicated, they will just be space separated. But the first and last words of the sentence can be compared with the others as well, and the first word starts with a capital letter while the last word ends with a period. I'll clarify this in the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## Base64 fixed point

It can be proven that there's exactly one string of infinite length that remain same after `base64` encoding [`Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZ...`](https://tio.run/##Ncy/DsIgEMfx3ae4DUixafzTBVl8BUfjcFZoDppioLoYnx1tQ9fv537n8I2pi/SctmN4mJxtiMBJNwrotDu2CqqKxAZg6W7ubu1u7kX8LH4VL@CzGACChvPLWhP5laST/iZUIbLAsZ7CZYo09pzdMZn2wESdBuoMb@ReaI2iXAN0YUxhMPUQ@v9QAlaMlWffnH8)

Given \$n\$, output one of

- the \$n\$-th character
- the first \$n\$ characters
- The whole string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: I don't understand this at all

Comment: A strings that starts with the outputted string? Doesn't every string begin with itself?

Comment: @mousetail `base64(x)` starts with `x`

Comment: It is confusing that your link starts with `V` and the test cases start with `m`. Also, [tag:fastest-code] requires specifying how exactly each submission will be scored https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info.

Comment: @pajonk The one starting with `m` is str.slice(\$3^0\$)

Comment: @pajonk Scoring thing isn't decided

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly fastest code - "most computation in fixed time" rather than  "fixed computation in least time". It should maybe be [tag:code-challenge] [tag:restricted-time]?

Comment: @pxeger [Largest input successfully processed within a fixed time limit.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info)

Answer (score 3):

---

### Definitions

A \$ \xi \$-word is defined as a string of letters such that every letter in the string appears an even number of times. For example, `aeaeccaa` is a \$ \xi \$-word.

The function \$ T \$, which operates on \$ \xi \$-words, is defined as follows:

1. Replace the odd-positioned (first, third, etc.) occurrences of each letter with `(`. For the example above, this produces `((ae(c(a`
2. Replace all the remaining letters (i.e., those that were the even occurrences) with `)`. For our example, this produces `(())()()`

This will always produce a string with balanced brackets.

### Task

Take, as input, a string \$ i \$, where every letter appears exactly twice (e.g. `xffcxc`). Note that this is a stricter condition than merely being a \$ \xi \$-word.

Return the lexicographically earliest \$ \xi \$-word, such that the input and output give the same value when \$ T \$ is applied to them.

Hint: a linear-time algorithm is possible.

### Rules

- You do not need to handle an empty input
- Letters are ASCII lowercase (`a` to `z`)
- You may choose to operate on integers instead of strings of letters. You can use any set of integers, as long as there are at least 26 of them.
- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

todo

---

## Sandbox notes

At the moment, this challenge is very abstract, which I think means it will look seem quite boring (until you start to actually solve it, which I think is fun, although fairly simple). (What kind of a title is *Lexicographically earliest \$ T \$-invariant \$ \xi \$-word*?)

If you can think of a good domain to make it concrete, I think it would be much better. (Unfortunately I can't reveal the original context in which I encountered it). At the least I will probably replace the symbolic names with cute names before posting.

Comment: How do you pronounce that?

Comment: @Jacob According to Google Translate, it's pronounced "she".

Answer (score 3):

## [Yakko's New World Order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257358/yakkos-new-world-order)

Comment: I don't think allowing outputting the indices into the list should be allowed

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Why not?

Comment: Everybody's just going to do that, and that rules out some interesting approaches involving the text itself (such as using some sort of custom digest as a sorting key).

Comment: _Given a list of countries in alphabetical order_ -> are we always given the full list, or could it be a subset of this list?

Comment: @Arnauld You are always given the full list. (If you want, you can ignore the input completely.)

Answer (score 3):

### Infinite Apple Dilemma

## [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257649/infinite-apple-dilemma)

Comment: +1 just cause Dennis

Comment: Are the third and fourth test-cases correct? - I get different results. Maybe the `20` and `30` are swapped?

Comment: @pajonk right lol

Comment: Will all the steps result in integer apple numbers (step-by-step)? Currently it's not true for test cases 5 and 6.

Comment: @pajonk nope, ty

Answer (score 3):

## [Reverse the polyglot, change the language.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257495/reverse-the-polyglot-change-the-language)

Answer (score 3):

## [Sum of Consecutive Squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/257458/114446)

Answer (score 3):

[Add two real numbers ... probably](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260284/add-two-real-numbers-probably)

Comment: @AnttiP The number of inputs which require reading an infinite number of bits like this has measure zero. The solution here is to simply loop forever in the tough cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [Whole Number Groups](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258088/91213)

Comment: Where does `1/7` come from in the second example?

Answer (score 3):

## [Approximate a root of an odd degree polynomial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258021/116074)

Comment: I've got a couple of answers so vote for to move to main page :p

Comment: The only note: usually \$a_i\$ means coefficient of polinomial

Answer (score 3):

### [Fibonacci Binary Squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258129/116013)

Comment: since this is a [tag:sequence], can we just use the default [tag:sequence] rules?

Comment: I'd be willing to allow the Fibonacci sequence used to generate the answer to be 0 or 1 indexed, but I don't see the logic in allowing the main "sequence" to be 0 indexed. The rest of the rules I think would be fine.

Comment: Well, some languages use zero-indexing for arrays, and some use one-indexing, so it can help.

Comment: Fair. Changed it to allow for 0- or 1- indexing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Help Me Type on My New Keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258227/107299)

Comment: In the 5th test case first letter of output must be `r` not `p`

Comment: It is very hard to read `q` as `я`... can we remove this rule? :) I'm not expert but I have never seen that Russians use `q` as `я`

Comment: JFYI they widely use `4` as `ч`, so if you want you also can add this rule

Comment: @EzioMercer 1. Thanks. My english kicked in. for 2. and 3. this is the specific keyboard layout im using. most mnemonic layouts ive used use `q` as `я`

Comment: Your task your rules :) Also please remove additional `space`  after second word in 5th test case

Comment: @EzioMercer read the comments after the test case: `note the double space after "chtec"`. its required because `c` is a combining letter

Comment: And the last question :) Are you sure about these rules: `"e" -> "е"`, `"je" -> "э"` and `"ye" -> "э"`? The letter `j` uses for `я,ё,ю` because in their pronunciation we have `й` at the start. `я - йа`, `ё - йо`, `ю - йу` and the same thing for letter `е - йэ`, so it is logical to have the these rules: `"je" -> "е"`, `"ye" -> "e"` and `"e" -> "э"`

Comment: About `c` you already have the rule `"c" -> "ц"` you don't need any additional `space` after it

Comment: @EzioMercer yes im sure. i know it seems weird. for the second comment, note `To type the single letters mapped to them, either press that key and then press space`

Comment: You have weird keyboard :)

Comment: In 5th test case `xepdyami` -> `xerdyami` - change the `p` to `r`

Comment: @EzioMercer aargh the challenges of being bilingual :P

Answer (score 3):

## ["Candy Crush" a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258201/candy-crush-a-string)

Comment: Suggested test case: `1322232223222311` -> (`1332223222311` -> `1333222311` -> `1222311` ->) `1311`. Since you mention you reiterate after every replacement from left to right again (well done for making that bold). :) If one would filter out all blocks of 3+ at once, it would incorrect result in -> `1333311` -> `111`  -> `""`. Good challenge overall, so +1 from me. And welcome to CGCC.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you for your feedback! I added your test case to the list :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Largest Binary Area](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258686/91213)

Comment: You may want to clarify that each column in ASCII art is a binary number. I had to read it a couple times before that was clear to me. Writing it out might probably be even clearer (e.g. "Take the sequence of all natural numbers in binary: `[1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111,10000,10001,...]`. Displaying each of these binary numbers as reversed columns gives: <insert current ascii-art here>") Apart from that the challenge is clear; nice challenge btw! I'm curious what kind of algorithms can be found instead of actually calculating the areas.

Answer (score 3):

## Calculate the p-adic square root of -1

Given a **prime** number \$p\$, a *[\$p\$-adic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)* is a number whose representation in base \$p\$ may have infinitely digits to the left of the radix point, but only finitely many digits to the right of it. A *\$p\$-adic integer* has no digits after the radix point.

\$p\$-adic numbers have some interesting properties. It can be proven that for any prime number \$p\$, there exists a \$p\$-adic integer \$x\$ such that \$x^2 = -1\$ if and only if the congruence \$x_0^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}\$ has a solution. (That is, there is some integer \$x_0\$ such that \$x_0^2 + 1\$ is divisible by \$p\$.)

Your task is to determine whether this is the case and calculate the digits of the number \$x\$. Note that there will always be two solutions which are additive inverses of each other; you only need to calculate one.

### Input

A prime number \$p \ne 2\$. (You don't need to verify that it's prime.)

### Output

Find the digits of the \$p\$-adic square root of \$-1\$, as described above. Following the standard `sequence` rules, do one of the following:

- Given an index \$i\$, output the \$i\$-th digit from the end. Since base representations are naturally 0-indexed, you may **not** use 1-indexing.
- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the last \$n\$ digits. You can choose between little-endian and big-endian.
- Output all digits in the form of a non-halting program, a generator, an infitite lazy list, etc.

If the \$p\$-adic square root of \$-1\$ does not exist, do anything that can be clearly distinguished from a valid output, such as raising an exception or returning an empty list.

### Algorithm

Here I describe one possible way to solve this challenge.

- Find a number \$x_0\$ between \$0\$ and \$p-1\$ such that \$x_0^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}\$. If not found, report failure.
- Find a number \$y\$ between \$0\$ and \$p-1\$ such that \$2x_0y \equiv 1 \pmod{p}\$. (This is always possible.)
- Let \$c_0 = \left\lfloor\frac{x_0}{p}\right\rfloor\$.
- For each positive integer \$i\$:

  - Let \$h_i = c_{i-1} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} x_j x_{i-j}\$.
  - Let \$x_i = (p-1-h_i)\cdot y \bmod p\$.
  - Let \$c_i = \left\lfloor\frac{h_i + 2 x_0 x_i}{p}\right\rfloor\$.
- The sequence \$\left(x_i\right)\$ is the output.

Ungolfed Python implementation:

```python
def sqrt_minus_one(p, n):
    for x in range(p):
        if (x * x + 1) % p == 0:
            last_digit = x
            break
    else:
        return None # no solution
    for x in range(p):
        if (x * 2 * last_digit) % p == 1:
            inv = x
    digits = [last_digit]
    carry = (last_digit * last_digit) // p
    for i in range(1, n):
        h = sum(digits[j] * digits[i - j] for j in range(1, i)) + carry
        digits.append((p - 1 - h) * inv % p)
        carry = (h + 2 * last_digit * digits[i]) // p
    return digits
```

**It's also possible to use a brute-force approach where you find an \$n\$-digit number \$x\$ such that \$x^2 + 1\$ ends with \$n\$ zeroes in base \$p\$. I suppose this could lead to much golfier solutions, so maybe I should make the challenge `restricted-complexity` to forbid this?**

### Test cases

```
  p | first 20 digits (two possible outputs)
  3 | ---
  5 | 2,1,2,1,3,4,2,3,0,3,2,2,0,4,1,3,2,4,0,4
    | 3,3,2,3,1,0,2,1,4,1,2,2,4,0,3,1,2,0,4,0
  7 | ---
 11 | ---
 13 | 5,5,1,0,5,5,1,0,1,8,8,6,12,6,3,0,4,7,4,5
    | 8,7,11,12,7,7,11,12,11,4,4,6,0,6,9,12,8,5,8,7
 17 | 4,2,10,5,12,16,12,8,13,3,14,0,6,1,0,15,1,8,14,5
    | 13,14,6,11,4,0,4,8,3,13,2,16,10,15,16,1,15,8,2,11
 47 | ---
101 | 10,5,29,66,10,30,44,29,72,25,34,82,83,5,52,17,67,94,65,52
    | 91,95,71,34,90,70,56,71,28,75,66,18,17,95,48,83,33,6,35,48
```

Comment: Perhaps allow assuming a square root of -1 exists? Testing for the existence of it isn't too related to finding it

Answer (score 3):

## [Is it traversable?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259083/is-it-traversable)

Answer (score 3):

## [Implement the `<=>` three-way comparison operator on numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259255/implement-the-three-way-comparison-operator-on-numbers)

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[comparison](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison)

Comment: How do the bonuses stack? Is the final score `(100-n)%` of the program length, or `0.99^n`?

Comment: @Bbrk24 just edited the bonuses bit; if your solution is `n` bytes, and your solution supports `k` numeric types, your score is `(100-(k-1)%) * n`.

Comment: The bonus disadvantages languages with less number types, and seems [non-observable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/92727). Additionally, in many languages you would have a solution which works for any comparable type, which can be user-defined. How would you define number types in that case? Regardless, [bonuses are usually recommended against](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/92727).

Comment: Axed the bonuses.

Answer (score 3):

## [Qat Equation Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259453/qat-equation-solver)

Comment: I think you should include both `.` and brackets, since they both add more power without being cumbersome. For example, I can't see how to express `A=(.);B=aAt;C=aAe` without using both of these.

Comment: @CommandMaster In that specific case, it could be expressed as `B=a.t;B=aAt;C=aAe`, but that makes me realize I should specify you can have more than one equation referencing the same variable I suppose

Answer (score 3):

### [Record Least Uncommon Multiple Counts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259488/116013)

Comment: You probably meant \$\frac{\text{lcm}}{\text{gcd}}\$, the other way around is less than 1

Comment: Good catch. I did

Answer (score 3):

## Rendevous!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Your bots went to the mall together, but they got lost!  Worse, they didn't agree on any strategy to find one another again.

Here's what they do know:

- There are \$n\$ stores, and bots can only meet each other in the stores.
- Each time step, each bot must choose one store to be in.
- Two bots go to the mall simultaneously.  Their score for the outing is the number of time steps it took for them to find one another.
- The mall closes after \$n^2\$ time steps.  If some bots are still at the mall, they will receive a score of \$n^2+1\$.

Bots must be written in Javascript.  Your bot must be a generator function, receiving a single input \$n\$ (the number of stores) and output at least \$n^2\$ integers in the range \$[0..n-1]\$.  Your bot's score will be the average of its scores when played with all of the other bots.

The stores will be scrambled - what is room 1 for one bot may be room 5 for another.  There will be many rounds of the game (1000 right now, but if there are lots of entries and it takes longer than an hour, I may lower that number), and each round will be a round-robin with a set number of stores.  \$n\$ will be in the range \$[4..25]\$.

There *are* better and worse strategies, but optimal strategies (when symmetric) are only known for \$n=2\$ and \$n=3\$.  An example bot (which will be playing):

```
function* randomSearchBot(n){
  while (true){
    yield Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
  }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}
function runRound(bot1, bot2, n){
    let b1 = bot1(n), b2 = bot2(n);
    let stores = Array(n).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
    shuffle(stores);
    let turn = 0;
    while (turn++ < n ** 2){
        if (b1.next().value == stores[b2.next().value]) break;
    }
    return turn;
}
function runAllRounds(...bots){
    const nameLength = Math.max(bots.map(b => b.name));
    bots = bots.map(b => {
        return {
            bot: b,
            totalScore: 0
        };
    });
    const rounds = 1000;
    let round = rounds;
    const pairs = bots.map((b, i) => bots.slice(i + 1).map(w => [b, w])).flat();
    while (round--){
        const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 22) + 4; // [4..25]
        for (let [a, b] of pairs) {
            const score = runRound(a.bot, b.bot, n);
            a.totalScore += score;
            b.totalScore += score;
        }
    }
    bots.forEach(b => {
        b.totalScore /= rounds * (bots.length - 1);
        console.log(b.bot.name.padEnd(nameLength) + ": " + b.totalScore.toFixed(5));
    });
}
```

The main feedback I'm looking for here is whether people think there's a big enough strategy space for it to be worth playing.

Comment: Ideally submissions would include the title and tags

Comment: When the bots are different I'm almost 100% one outputting a fixed output and the other outputting a permutation is optimal.

Comment: If both bots output random permutations I believe the expected score is around \$ \frac e{e-1}n \$.

Comment: I believe it is exactly \$ n+1 - \frac{ !(n+1) - n\cdot !n}{n!-!n} \$, or approximately \$ n + \frac{e-2}{e-1}\$, so it's ever so slightly worse than random search bot.

Answer (score 3):

## [Shortest distinguishable slice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259707/) (posted)

Comment: ime, it's more common to express ranges as `[start, end + 1)` rather than `[start, end]` -- that's what most C++ STL functions do, for example. Would that be accepted here?

Comment: @Jacob what I think Bbrk24 meant was that in a lot of languages, `"abcdef"[1:4]` would be `bcd` not `bcde` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQykxKTklNU0p2tDKJFbz/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online")). Obviously it's your challenge, your rules, but IMO it might be worth allowing this format of slices as the output instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `[start, end)` not `[start, end + 1)` since the latter is the same as `[start, end]`.

Comment: @TheThonnu Yeah you are right, fixing now

Comment: Now this part requires fixing (or removing): `A slice can also be 1 character long if the two indices are equal.`

Comment: @pajonk Oh, duh. This is why the sandbox is so useful lol

Answer (score 3):

## [The Jaccard Index](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259881/the-jaccard-index)

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation for those of us who haven’t studied set theory?

Comment: @Jacob I added some historical background, a revised explanation and a few links for the set theory operations. Let me know if I missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## How super is this prime?

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259875/110951)

Comment: To me, this sounds like functions are disallowed - is that intentional?

Comment: @CreativeName No; I'll edit it

Answer (score 3):

## [Calculate Bloons RBE Equivalent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260075/calculate-bloons-rbe-equivalent)

Answer (score 3):

## International Resource Trading KOTH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Your country wants to reach Mars, and do it as cheaply as possible. While you can produce all required resources domestically, other countries can produce them cheaper and trading can drastically reduce both your costs.

### Goal of the game

There are 10 resources, numbered 1-10. You need 1,000 of each resource to build a rocket and colonize Mars.

The cost of each rocket is different for each player though. One will cost €10, one €20, €30, ... and the last costs €100 per unit. This number is different for every bot, for example resource 1 could cost €20 for one but but €90 for a different bot.

Without trading, the rocket would cost €550,000. But if you import resources that are expensive for you to produce, and sell resources that are cheap for you to produce. If you do it right, you can make the process massively cheaper or even potentially make a profit and still launch your rocket.

### The game loop

The game consists of 7 rounds. Each round has 2 phases.

The first phase is the production phase. Each bot can choose to produce some number of resources locally. The total limit for how much you can produce is 10 the first round, 20, 40, 80 ... 1280 in the last round. Bots can choose to divide their production among every resource. For example, you can buy 6 of resource A and 4 of resource B in the first round. Money will be subtracted from your score proportional to the value the resource has for you.

The second phase is the trading phase. In turns, every bot has the option offer a trade. Then other bots can choose to accept the offer or to create a counteroffer. Then the bot may choose to accept any of the counteroffers or reject all of them.

Trades can either be money for resources or resources for money. You can't trade resources for resources directly.

There are 3 rounds of trading for every production phase.

If the game ends before you collect enough to launch your rocket, the rest of the resources will be produced domestically and cost you the domestic production price.

### Example bot

```py
class PriceBelowHalf:
    """
    Will only buy resources if the price is less than half the local production price
    Will only sell resources if the price is more than double the local production price
    """

    def __init__(self, bot_ids: list[int], resource_prices: dict[int, int], rng):
        # Randomness only allowed via the provided RNG.
        self.bot_ids = bot_ids
        self.resource_prices = resource_prices

    def production_phase(self, max_production: int, resources: dict[int, int]):
        # produce the maximum amount of the cheapest resource
        return {min(self.resource_prices, key=lambda i:resource_prices[i]): max_production}
    
    def trade(self, resources: dict[int, int]):
        # Offer to buy the resource we have the least of for half it's price
        resource = min(resources, key=lambda i:resources[i])

        # 2 item tuples are treated as resources, single integers are treated as money
        # First element is what you get, second is what you want to give
        return [(resource, 10),
                self.resource_prices[resource]*5]

    def trade_offer_accepted(self, resources: dict[int, int], counteroffers: list):
        for counteroffer in counteroffers:
            # Accept the first counteroffer that is a good deal
            if isinstance(counteroffer[0], tuple) and \
               counteroffer[0][1] * 2 > self.resource_prices[counteroffer[0][0]] * counteroffer[1]:
                return counteroffer

    def trade_offer_received(self, trade_offer: list, resources:dict[int, int]):
        # If you return a offer in the same format it would be treated as a counteroffer
        # Counteroffer must be for the same resource but you may change both the amount of money and the amount of the resource
        # If you want to unconditionally accept simply `return trade_offer`
        # If you return None you will reject the offer
        # third element of the trade offer is the bot that offered it

        # they want to give a resource for money
        if isinstance(trade_offer[0], tuple):
            # Must be greater than 2:1 ratio to our own price
            return [[counteroffer[0][0], counteroffer[0][1]],
                    # Pay half price or the other bot offered, whatever is cheaper
                    min(
                        self.resource_prices[counteroffer[0][0]] * counteroffer[0][1]] // 2,
                        trade_offer[1]
                    )
            ]
        else:
            # They want to give money for our resources, so we need to check if we have enough
            if resources[trade_offer[1][0]]>=trade_offer[1][1]:
                return [
                    max(
                        trade_offer[0],
                        self.resource_prices[trade_offer[1][0]] * trade_offer[1][1]
                    ),
                    trade_offer[1]
                ]
```

### Extra Rules

- No IO
- No RNG except via the provided seeded PRNG
- No exploiting the controller
- No targeting a specific bot or specifically helping one specific bot. Hurting or helping a range of strategies is perfectly fine.

Comment: Suggestion: Use the ¤ generic currency symbol

Comment: @Ginger I'd rather not

Comment: Instead, use $, as it’s ASCII

Comment: It really isn't a issue for the bots, all math is plain integers. So whether the currency is ASCII doesn't matter at all. I prefer to use € since I'm from europe, but you are free to imagine the currency as pounds or yen or whatever. It really doesn't matter for the challenge. If there are any genuine concerns about the challenge instead of bikeshedding about the currency symbol used I'd love to hear it.

Comment: If multiple bots accept an offer, who gets it?  Do all bots see all offers, even ones that have already been accepted?

Comment: Do bots get any info about other bots' production prices?

Comment: @Spitemaster Every bot can choose which counteroffer to accept, and they do not get info on others production prices

Comment: @Spitemaster I'm not sure yet if all bots will see all offers. I like the idea of being able to limit a trade offer to a certain subset of bot as a way to hide information but I'm afraid it would make the game too complex

Answer (score 3):

## Complex remainder

Complex remainder can be defined in a similar way to real remainder as \$ y - x \lfloor \frac y x \rfloor \$. However this depends on a suitable complex floor function. There are a number of ways of defining a complex floor function (for at least one of which there has been a previous challenge), but for this challenge I will relax the requirements to the following:

- Every complex number has exactly one floor which is a Gaussian integer.
- \$ \lfloor z \rfloor = \lfloor \Re ( z ) \rfloor \$ if \$ \Im (z) = 0 \$.
- \$ \lfloor z + n \rfloor = \lfloor z \rfloor + n \$ where \$ n \$ is a Gaussian integer.

Note that this implies that \$ \lfloor n \rfloor = n \$ for every Gaussian integer \$ n \$.

Please write a program or function that will perform complex remainder using a compatible definition.

Even if your language supports complex numbers you can choose to input them as separate real and imaginary parts. You can also choose to support only Gaussian integers as inputs and outputs.

If your language has suitable builtins for remainder or floor then you can earn extra brownie points by providing an additional solution that doesn't use them.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: Maybe some test cases?

Comment: How about negative numbers? There are, rather famously, multiple ways to give a sign to a remainder involving negative numbers.

Comment: @Adám I didn't want to provide test cases as they would assume a certain complex floor function. Also, the use of floor makes the result consistent for negative numbers (i.e. it's like Pascal's `mod` rather than `rem`).

Comment: How do we demonstrate correctness of a submission?

Comment: @Adám Probably showing that `(y-y%x)/x` is a Gaussian integer and `(y+x)%x` and `(y+ix)%x` both equal `y%x` for multple random test cases would be enough.

Comment: You should probably explicitly say a Gaussian integer is a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are integers to avoid an inevitable comment about it. Similarly, adding your response to Adám's question will probably save you some time.

Comment: Will there ever be some different floor functions \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$ both satisfy the requirement but have at least one \$x\in\mathbb{C}\$ that \$f_1(x)\ne f_2(x)\$? What if we change the second requirement into simply \$\lfloor 0\rfloor = 0\$?

Comment: @tsh Yes it's quite easy to have different satisfactory floor functions. I do want real modulus to continue to work as expected though.

Answer (score 3):

Given an integer, output `an` if its English name begins with a vowel (namely it is positive, and its first digit is `8` or it has the form `11` followed by a multiple of 3 digits), and otherwise output `a`.  This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Test cases

```
10: a
0: a
8234987: an
110: a
11: an
11234: an
-8: a
-11: a
8: an
```

Note for the sandbox viewers: in the related question [English An or A?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235345/english-an-or-a) the input is an arbitrary word as a string, and in the related question [An A , or An An?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93264/an-a-or-an-an) the article a/an must be placed inside a sentence, properly capitalized.  The present question has a more minimalistic input and output.

Comment: I feel like this is just arbitrarily adding a change to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235345/english-an-or-a), as the answers would be pretty much the same except with the added conversion from integer to cardinal

Comment: @emirps A solution to this could easily shortcut that using the pattern noted in the question body. Although a language with appropriate builtins might find the most direct approach shortest, I'd almost hesitate to call the challenges related at all.
In any case, I'd recommend relaxing the output to make this a [tag:decision-problem], and *possibly* also excluding negative numbers from the input. Also, perhaps make it explicit that we don't have to handle octillions :P

Comment: Good point about the word octillion, although that cannot come up as the first word in the number's name, right?

Answer (score 3):

## [Turn strings into hexagonal spirals!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261077/turn-strings-into-hexagonal-spirals)

Comment: Should it be *hexagon* or *hexagonal* spirals? Confused as an ESL, both sound correct to me. Perhaps they are?

Comment: Since you mentioned "_You may start the spiral at any of the 6 points you like._", does this mean [this](https://pastebin.com/0UxEqXG1) would be a valid output for the first example as well? All your test cases and examples start at the top-left corner. As for the question in your comment, I'm not a native English speaker, but I'm pretty sure both _hexagon spirals_ and _hexagonal spirals_ are correct, as well as _spirals of hexagons_. I see all three used when I randomly google around.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah, it would be valid output. I will include it as an example, thanks! I think I will change the title to _hexagonal_ spirals since that's how I'd have said it in my native language, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

## Find the centroid of a spherical polygon on Earth

[codge-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codge-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given a list of `N` (latitude, longitude) coordinates in [decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), `coord={{lat1,lon1},{lat2, lon2}, ...,{latN,lonN}}`, we consider the [spherical polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Spherical_polygons) enclosed by the geodesics connecting successive pairs of coordinates (including the geodesic between the last and first pair of coordinates). We will follow the convention that the enclosed polygon is always to the left as we traverse each geodesic, i.e., the coordinates are given counter-clockwise around the boundary.

Your task is to find the coordinates of the **centroid** (center of mass) of the spherical polygon (technically, the projection of the centroid onto the surface of the Earth).

For example, the coordinates `{{0,0}, {60,0}, {0, -90}}` define a spherical triangle with a centroid at `{24.5839, -37.5891}`:

[image: Simple Example]

### Specifications and Assumptions

- Assume a perfectly spherical earth with a radius of 1.
- At least 3 coordinates will be specified; there could be arbitrarily many. All the coordinates will be distinct and properly define a spherical polygon in counter-clockwise ordering (no crossing geodesics, no zero-area polygons, no lunes, etc.).
- To avoid edge cases and indeterminate inverse trig evaluations, all given coordinates will be confined to a single hemisphere. Furthermore, you do not need to handle inputs that would result in a centroid at the North or South Pole nor a longitude of +180=-180 degrees. (These would be valid inputs though!).
- The input format is flexible: list of lists, array, .csv file, etc. The output coordinates of the centroid should be given to at least 3 decimal places in the decimal degree format, but may otherwise be returned as you see fit.

### One possible approach

One possible approach is a neat application of Stokes' Theorem, partially illustrated in this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897187/locating-the-centroid-center-of-mass-of-spherical-polygons/38201499#38201499), and is outlined as follows:

1. Duplicate and append the first pair of coordinates: `{{lat1,lon1},{lat2, lon2}, ...,{latN,lonN}, {lat1,lon1}}`
2. Convert these lat/long coordinates to unit vectors in Cartesian (rectangular) coordinates, \$\vec{v_i}\$, \$i=1,...,N+1\$. NB. Latitude is measured in degrees away from equator (\$xy\$-plane) as opposed to the common mathematical convention of measuring [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) from \$z\$-axis.
3. Compute the sum \$\vec{c} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{ \vec{v_i} \times \vec{v_{i+1}}}{\Vert \vec{v_i} \times \vec{v_{i+1}} \Vert} \mathrm{ang}(\vec{v_i}, \vec{v_{i+1}})\$ to find the 3D Cartesian coordinates of appropriate moment, where \$\times\$ is the [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and \$\mathrm{ang}(\vec{a}, \vec{b})\$ is the angle between vectors \$\vec{a}\$ and \$\vec{b}\$. (Note that \$\mathrm{ang}\$ can return either radians xor degrees, so long as it does so consistently. The choice of degrees vs radians effectively corresponds to a rescaling of the sphere, which is cancelled out in the following normalization step.)
4. Normalize \$\vec{c}\$ to project the centroid to the surface of the sphere, \$\vec{c}/\Vert \vec{c} \Vert \$.
5. Convert these Cartesian coordinates to lat/long using inverse trig functions.

Be careful to mind radians vs degrees and inverse trig function ranges within your chosen language. Also, some parts of this given algorithm may or may not be superfluous...

### More Test Cases

`{{0, 170}, {-90, 0}, {0, -160}}` has a centroid of `{-32.7795, -175.0000}`

`{{26.158, -80.326}, {35.803, -78.722}, {36.103, -115.178}, {32.791, -96.81}}` has a centroid of `{33.9037, -90.7267}`

`{{52.37, 4.89}, {41.89, 12.5}, {37.98, 23.73}, {46.06, 14.51}, {52.52, 13.38}, {52.26, 21.02}, {60.17, 24.94}}` has a centroid of `{50.0215, 14.5968}`

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)--shortest byte count wins!
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), standard exclusions forbidden.

## E: Sandbox Questions

Any comments on difficulty/question scope? I think the connection with lat/long coordinates on earth is a nice motivation, but about half of my program to generate test cases is purely coordinate conversions. For reference, my very un-golfed program (complete with camelCase function names) is ~500 bytes.

There are certainly ways to make the task simpler or more complex:

- The easiest version (I think) would be to forget about the earth and lat/long entirely and have a purely geometric question. Inputs and outputs as unit Cartesian vectors.
- A harder version would not use a spherical earth approximation, but rather require an ellipsoidal earth or even a proper [geodetic datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum). However, I think this becomes very difficult very quickly--even finding a geodesic on a geoid is hard, let alone the given algorithm requiring proper (numerically approximated) line integrals rather than a sum. Simultaneously, the task would likely become trivial with commercial GIS software. Using a more accurate earth model does significantly impact the centroid coordinates, changing it by up to several degrees for the given test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [Logarithmic incrementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/261321/117478)

Comment: Is there precedent in using $x\ast$ for the length of a list? I've always encountered $#x$.

Comment: @RubenVerg just thought I’d use that notation. I don’t think it matters.

Comment: You're also missing an indication for empty lists: either say that they never occur or specify what the value should be

Comment: @RubenVerg fixed

Comment: actually, f([n, n, n, ..., n]) = n + 1 for any list length, which is even more interesting (and trivially provable)

Comment: Can we get some test cases please?

Comment: @TheThonnu test cases have been made.

Answer (score 3):

## Vanilla Natural Logarithm Challenge [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[There is a challenge for multiplying two numbers so I guess this counts too](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/106182/91213)

Given as input a positive real number `n` compute its natural logarithm.

Your answer should be within \$10^{-6}\$ for \$1 \leq n \leq 10\$ and within \$10^{-3}\$ for \$0.1 \leq n \leq 100\$. You don't need to handle numbers outside this range.

See [this thread on mathematics.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61279/1096272) for various approaches to this problem. Just for inspiration, feel free to use a method not on that page.

Using builtins for logarithms is discouraged but not forbidden. Consider marking your language as "community wiki" if you just use a builtin.

### Test Cases

| x | ln(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | -2.3025850929940455 |
| 0.25 | -1.3862943611198906 |
| 0.5 | -0.6931471805599453 |
| 0.75 | -0.2876820724517809 |
| 0.9 | -0.10536051565782628 |
| 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 1.3 | 0.26236426446749106 |
| 2 | 0.6931471805599453 |
| 2.718281828459045 | 1.0 |
| 3.141592653589793 | 1.1447298858494002 |
| 4 | 1.3862943611198906 |
| 5 | 1.6094379124341003 |
| 7 | 1.9459101490553132 |
| 10 | 2.302585092994046 |
| 53 | 3.970291913552122 |
| 54.59815003314423 | 4.0 |
| 99 | 4.59511985013459 |

### IO

Standard IO rules apply. Importantly, you may take input as a fraction if you prefer. You may also output as a fraction, which does not need to be fully reduced.

Comment: "Using builtins" — surely one must use *some* buildins‽

Comment: @Adám Not really… there are methods for doing this.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian I can't imagine solving this without any builtins.

Comment: @Adám just needs a for loop and the 4 basic arithmetic operations

Comment: According to Adam those are technically builtins, I've clarified though so there is no need to further pollute the comments

Comment: Is there any reason for the increased accuracy requirement between 1 and 10?

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian most approximations are more accurate around that range

Comment: You deserve an upvote. Anyways, I have a programme in mind that just requires me to increase a k value if it isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 3):

## Lowest digit addition generator

A *digit addition generator* of an integer `n` is any integer `x` that satisfy the equation `x + s(x) = n`, with `s(x)` being the sum of the digits of `x`. (We will work under base 10 for convenience.)

For example, a digit addition generator for `29` would be `19`, because `19 + (1 + 9) = 29`. Some numbers have more than one generator. An example might be `216`, which has generators of `198` and `207`.

Your objective is to generate the **lowest** digit addition generator of every non-negative integer `n`, and output *anything other than a non-negative integer* if there is none for `n`.
The non-negative terms in your result should match the sequence [A096234](https://oeis.org/A096234). You may find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.14365.pdf) related to the challenge.

Fewest bytes win; standard rules apply.

[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: Do [tag:sequence] rules apply? (Since you haven't put any tags)

Comment: This doesn't output any sequence, to my knowledge... the program should accept an integer and output another. Maybe I should get that edited in.

Comment: It might be shorter to just output the LDA for every number in sequence infinitely

Comment: After 2 minutes of introspect, I realized that the OEIS didn't exist for nothing... Time to add a new tag and also a rewrite.

Comment: I'd also suggest allowing any non-positive value, not just -1 on errors. Something like `None` or `""` could be shorter depending on the language.

Comment: @mousetail Edited. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Code Golf, and thanks for using the Sandbox!

Comment: @TomEpsilon I feel like still @mousetails' suggestion isn't fully implemented - `None` doesn't fit the "any negative number" definition for when there is no generator.

Comment: I agree, and plan to implement the wording of "anything other than a non-negative integer".

Comment: Edit successful. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Alright. If there is none, I shall post it on the site.

Answer (score 3):

## [Compute the maximal Ducci period](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/262623/81203)

Answer (score 3):

## [Meta-cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263283/meta-cat-program)

Comment: Just replacing `"` with `\"` isn't sufficient, is it? I'd probably use `JSON.stringify` or another function with more edge-case handling.

Comment: @Bbrk24 you can put _anything_ except unescaped double quotes inside a double quote string. Same with single quotes. The only issue is if you use backticks (because you have to escape the ${} stuff)

Comment: It won’t handle unescaped backslashes or newlines in the input.

Comment: @Bbrk24 fixed now

Comment: Still doesn’t handle unescaped line breaks (you can only have those in template strings, not double-quoted strings)

Comment: @Bbrk24 should be fixed now

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should works for any Unicode strings since ES2019 or any ASCII strings since maybe ES5.

Answer (score 3):

### Battle Chess Royale (Any better name?)

[koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth)

---

Imagine a large chess board where different players can choose and place a chess piece. Pieces are Knights, Bishops, Rooks, Kings or Queens. Each piece has an unique movement ability and a point per turn value. The board, after an specific amount of rounds will shrink (as a battle royale field do) disqualifying any player that left its piece outside.

The goal of the game is to get as many points as you can. This can be achieved by simply staying within the safe zone of the board and killing other players to take their points.

Each piece has an specific amount of passive points per turn based on how freely it can move. Below is the table used. Feel free to give any suggestion on point distribution.

[image]

*Note: Pawns are not added to the game since their movement is similar to a king*

For the game, you will select which piece type you wanna play with. The function for your bot will take as a parameter a board (n x n matrix), an array with the available moves your piece can perform, a list with the next players, and finally an object with info about the game (next shrinking round, leaderboard, etc...). Your return value should be your desired move (must be from your available move array).

---

### Bots Examples

```
new Bishop(function(board, availableMoves, players, gameInfo){
    return availableMoves[0];
}, "Drunky Step");
```

---

```
new Rook(
    (board, availableMoves, players, gameInfo) => 
          availableMoves[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableMoves.length)], 
    "Le Rook"
)
```

---

```
new Queen(function(board, availableMoves, players, gameInfo){
    let targets = availableMoves.filter(move => {
        return board[move[0]][move[1]] != null;
    });
    if(targets.length > 0)
        return targets[0];
    else
        return availableMoves[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableMoves.length)];
}, "Killer")
```

Here is an example of a 5x5 board with 2 bishops in it

[image]

---

### Notes

- The game will be turn based.
- Players are randomly shuffled before the beginning of the game
- There is an specific amount of rounds where you cant capture anyone
- Board always shrinks towards the center
- If you die or get captured, you score remains
- It is possible to die because of board shrink, and still win the game
- There is no suicide unless you wait for board shrink

---

**Questions:**

- Has this been made?
- Config options as # of rounds, board size, how many rounds every shrink, etc... can be set up before the game. What values should I use?
- Any considerations I should take?

---

PD: I have most of the controller done, I'll be uploading it soon. I'm still working on some basic graphic interface.

Comment: Why would anyone select bishop, rook or king if the queen can do more?

Comment: @SuperStormer You would earn less points per turn using a queen instead of some other piece. The queen has a better attacking capabilities but her pasive income is low compared to other pieces

Comment: What can I do with the money?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev points is what defines the leadership, who is winning xD

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz So if I get lots of money, it’s ok to die soon?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev That could be a strategy, I just dont know how good it would be

Answer (score 3):

## [Diagonalize a vector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262809/diagonalize-a-vector)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)[linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)

Comment: +1 because this is an opportunity for less usable languages to do well or at least be able to compete. Could you add two or three test cases?

Comment: if $n = 0$, must the result be a 0x0 matrix (if such a concept exists in the language), or is a 0-element vector acceptable?

Comment: @RubenVerg yes, that's fine

Answer (score 3):

### Sleep Forever

Write a program that never exits completely, but also after startup consumes exactly 0.0 CPU time.

This means you must sleep in a way that the operation system never wakes up the process. `ps aux | grep [your program]` should show `%CPU` `0.0` at any time after startup.

Note a long sleep in a loop is not enough, since then the OS will need to wake up your program to start the next iteration. You must absolutely never be woken up.

Waking up on signals for the purpose of exiting is OK if your language does that by default. However, no normal input over pipes should not wake your program up.

You can use CPU for any finite amount of time during startup.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.

### Meta:

I need some help with the signals exception. I don't want submissions to need to spend a large amount of code to disable all signal handlers present by default, but also I don't want programs that just "wait for a keypress" for example which isn't really reasonable.

I also want to avoid giving significant advantages to languages just because of what signal handlers they do/do not have by default.

I also want to avoid using too much OS specific terminology.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is waiting for input or confirmation OK? E.g. JS `alert()`

Comment: @Adám No, I could use help how to specify that clearly though

Comment: What is `px`? I don't seem to have it, though Ubuntu says I can get it with apt.

Comment: @Bbrk24 I guess they meant `ps`

Answer (score 3):

## [Print this pulsar (or "Print this diamond" gone beautifully wrong)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263135/print-this-diamond-gone-beautifully-wrong)

Comment: Even better than a diamond!

Answer (score 3):

### Fast and Golfiest Challenges

I am planning on creating a series of cops-and-robbers style challenges. My inspiration is the coexistance of code efficiency problems and code golfing problems on this site - and the problem that code efficiency challenges seem to be often overlooked, even though most of competitive programming is centered upon efficiency. So I plan to combine the two in order to let golfers on the site try considering code efficiency as well, and as an opportunity for competitive programming experts to show off their cool knowledge of segment trees and the Bellman-Ford ;-) (alright, maybe not such hard stuff since I still want the challenge to be accessible to most people, especially golfers).

So here comes my idea. Each challenge in the series will be based on one theme (for instance, one theme I have in mind is "The Lords of the Strings", aimed at string operations).

The cops will choose a problem (the difficulty must not be "easy") on the competitive coding platform LeetCode and *independently* (there's no way to do anti-cheat for this, though, so we'll leave it up to the integrity of the participants themselves) write a both efficient *and* golfed answer for it. The problem should not be too easy. However, for the cops efficiency is emphasized over golfiness.

The robbers need to improve on the cops' code by golfing up the code (in the same language as the cop's), but here comes the thing: the golfed up version must not be algorithmically slower than the cop version. The robber has to prove this by theoretically proving that the time complexity of their code is lower or equal to the cop code. If it is lower, the robber gets 2.718 times their normal score (will still be rounded to the nearest integer).

Both cops and robbers must report the UTC time of their answer post. The cop's score is the number of hours (rounded to the nearest whole) that pass before the first valid robber answer is posted. The robber's score is the percentage reduction of code bytes compared to the cop code, again rounded to the nearest whole number.

What do you think, community? Any suggestions are very welcome! Thanks in advance :-D

*TL;DR*: An unusual cops and robbers game. Cops choose a competitive programming problem under a certain theme and write code to solve it. Robbers golf up the cop's code but must not sacrifice efficiency in the process. Cops mainly aim for code efficiency, while robbers mainly aim for code golfing.

### Example

**Cop**

Input `n`, output `2*n` (in the actual challenge please go get a real problem on LeetCode and paste the link).

Code: `,[>+>+<<-]>>[<+>-]<.` (Brainfuck, 20 bytes)

*2 hours and 40 minutes later...*

**Robber**

Code: `,[>+>+<<-]>[>+<-]>.` (19 bytes)

Both have complexity `O(n)`.

**Results**: Cop gets 3 points (3 hours before first solve) and robber gets 5 points (5% reduction in code length).

Comment: Thanks so much for people on The Nineteenth Byte for their suggestions!

Comment: [challenge post on main site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263049)

Answer (score 3):

## [Hashers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264161/hashers-and-crashers-cops) and [Crashers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264164/hashers-and-crashers-robbers)

Comment: You might want to add an example cop and crack.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51068/cryptographic-hash-golf)

Comment: @noodleman added

Comment: @Bbrk24 it seems exactly the same except of the scoring system, is that enough to make it not a duplicate? Edit: I just realized the other challenge hashes numbers instead of strings.

Comment: How does this work when there is more than one collision? For (a poor) example, if my hash last_char(input) and no one cracks it I might say that the collision was "longstringyousee" and "bigscore" giving me a score of 24, but clearly "a" and "ba" are also a collision. One could imagine more complex (that actually have a chance at not being cracked) hashes that allow arbitrarily sized collisions.

Comment: @CursorCoercer for cops the shorter collision is better.

Comment: Ah right, I got mixed up in my train of thought, I was concerned about the robber scoring. It probably won't be much of a problem anyways, but just something to keep in mind

Comment: What if a cop just copy-pastes a SHA256 implementation? lol

Comment: @ShiranYuan They would have to know a collision in the SHA256 hash system for the answer to be valid, so the US government would be very interested.

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev Ok so maybe sending the challenge out would help CGCC get government attention and thus more publicity :P

Comment: @ShiranYuan huh?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev just joking lol

Comment: @CursorCoercer Standard CnR rules are that unintended cracks are still valid, so if I find a shorter crack than the cop intended, scoring works the same as if that was the intended solution.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms yes, that’s true.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dual scoring criterion challenge concept]

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) (that's right...three OWC tags on one post :p)

---

Inspired by [The Fast and the Golfiest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263049/cops-fast-and-golfiest-season-1-the-lord-of-the-strings), I've come up with what might be a novel way to do a combined code golf/fastest code challenge. I haven't decided what the actual task would be, but here's how it would work:

Your score is the number of answers you outgolf, plus the number of answers you outperform.

This means the highest possible score is \$2(n-1)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of answers. The idea is that an answer *could* focus purely on golfing or on speed, and get a score close to \$n-1\$, but achieving a balance of the two is the only way to do better than that.

Since this scoring method depends on having many answers to compare against, I'm thinking it would work differently from our site's normal rules, and all languages would compete against one another (this is more commonly treated as true in [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)). In order to keep the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) side of things fair, any language (including a specific flag combination) used must have at least <s>10</s> 2 answers, which must meet **any** of the following requirements:

- Posted by a user other than OP
- Posted before the challenge
- Posted at least two months ago

This limits flag abuse and other tricks to a more acceptable degree. Common flags in flag-abuse-oriented languages like Japt or Vyxal might still be usable, but most languages which have these sorts of flags are enormously uncompetitive in performance.

That's another reason I want to make all languages compete; it makes choosing the language you use an opportunity to strategize. A faster language like C might beat more answers in speed, while losing badly on golfiness, while the reverse may be true for Jelly or Vyxal.

Comment: [Myxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Myxal) ought to do well.

Comment: Wow, cool thing my challenge inspired others :-) 

I think it's a cool idea but it's hard to measure performance. We need to find an extremely stable interpreter/compiler for every single language if we wanna do that, and it's just difficult overall.

Still, the idea itself is very cool.

Comment: @ShiranYuan Testing a few dozen times on the same hardware with countermeasures taken to minimize random noise should make the scoring much more consistent, I think. And any time the distribution of times from two submissions overlaps enough that it's hard to say with certainty which is faster, could always just run a dozen more tests. It's imperfect, but should work fine

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Well, good luck establishing the protocol ;-)

Comment: @ShiranYuan I mean, we do already have quite a few [tag:fastest-code] questions. I'd probably just add in some statistics to make it more rigorous, and set up my test machine in such a way that consistent performance is more likely (I've got a server which I'm going to be using for hosting an online interpreter with code timing functionality, so this will sort of be like an opportunity to get that sort of isolation set up)

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Well what if someone submits code in esoteric languages that have no "canon" interpreter, like Brainfuck?

Comment: @ShiranYuan A specific implementation would be required to be specified (and it would anyway, given that, e.g., BF has a wide range of unspecified behaviors that different interpreters vary on)

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Nice idea! I think it's pretty good to go ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## Simulate Keyboard Inputs

### Background

You know how in text editors and just text fields in general, there's always that blinking bar where you type? Yeah, simulate typing there.

You'll be given 3 inputs: The current text field, the position of the cursor, and the input sequence.

Here's an example:

```
Hello, World!
5
[U];[U];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[U];i;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];.
=> Hi, World.
```

Firstly, the number 5 tells us that the cursor is here, represented by the asterisk: `Hello*, World!`. If you take the string as zero-indexed, and choose the left side, you will find the cursor's starting point.

Next, we have 2 `[U]`s. `[U]` is a special input, representing undo. However, there is nothing to undo, so nothing happens.

Then, we have 5 `[B]`s. `[B]` is another special input, representing backspace. This tells us to erase 5 characters to the left of the cursor, one at a time. This gives `*, World!`.

Next, we have `[U]`. This tells us to cancel out the previous input (if there's anything to cancel out). If you have two `[U]`s, then you cancel out the last two instructions before the `[U]`s. Logic extends to all number of `[U]`s. Cancelling out the previous input, we have `H*, World!`.

Next, we have `i`. If there are no square brackets around the character, just add it to the text as a string, to the left of the cursor: `Hi*, World!`.

Now, we have 9 `[R]`s. `[R]` represents Move Cursor Right, so we move the cursor right 9 times: `Hi, World!*`. Note how it only actually takes 8 `[R]`s to get to the end, so the final `[R]` doesn't do anything.

Now, a `[B]`. This gives us `Hi, World*`.

Finally, `.`. This gives us `Hi, World.`.

//

The list of special inputs is shown here:

```
[B] = Backspace
[U] = Undo
[R] = Move Cursor Right
[L] = Move Cursor Left
```

Of course, within reason, you can change these special inputs (as long as it won't conflict with any non-special inputs.

//

With regards to other rules:

- Left or Backspace when the cursor is furthest left does nothing.
- Right when the cursor is furthest right also does nothing.
- Undo when there's nothing to undo also does nothing.

### Your Task

- Sample Input:

1. The current text field
2. The position of the text cursor (<= length of current text field)
3. The input sequence

Wrt the input sequence, in my examples I have used a string where each instruction is separated by semicolons. You can take the input sequence in any reasonable format - but note that the no input can contain this character. You can expect the non-special inputs and the text field to contain no `\n`s or `\t`s. They will also not contain any `[B]`s, `[`, or whatever you're using for making the special input unique.

- Output: Return the final text field, after the sequence has been executed.

**Test Cases**

```
Input => Output

Hello, World!
5
[U];[U];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[U];i;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];.
=> Hi, World.

3987^12 + 4365^12 = 4472^12
27
[L];[B];[L];[L];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[U];[U];[L];[U];[R];[B];5;[L];[L];[L];[L];[B];[L];[B];[B];[B];[L];[L];[R];[R];[L];[L];[L];[L];[L];[B];[L];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];4;[B];3"
=> 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2

I kinda don't like pepperoni on pizza, yknow?
0
[B];[B];[B];[L];[L];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[U];[B];[B];[B];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R]; ;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];[R];[R]; and garlic too actuallyk;[B];[U];[U]
=> I kinda do like pepper onion pizza, yknow?

This is [tag:code-golf], so shortest answer wins.
13
[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];c;h;s;[U];a;[R];[R];[B];[B];[R];L;[U];[L];llenge;[R];r;[L];[B];[R];[B];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];[B];[B];[B];[B];b;[R];[R];[L];[U];[R];[R];response or ;[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[R];[B];[B];[B];[B];ill accepted as answer.;[U];ill be accepted as answer!
=> This is [tag:code-challenge], so best response or answer will be accepted as answer!
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Comment: IMO, a title that's something like "Simulate keyboard inputs" would be better, as the challenge doesn't really have much to do with the blinking cursor. Also, can we choose what value represents each special input (within reason, of course)?

Comment: @SuperStormer Noted, title changed. Also, sure - within reason. Adding that now.

Comment: Am I allowed to take a list of characters with special characters as a singleton list?

Answer (score 3):

## [Calculating Transitive Closure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263566/calculating-transitive-closure)

Comment: Wouldn't the output for the empty relation be 0? It satisfies the condition for being transitive.

Comment: I think the task might be easier to understand, if you add a purely graph theoretic explanation. If I understood it correctly a graph is transitively closed iff any two vertices that are connected by a directed path (or cycle) are also connected by an edge.

Comment: @bsoelch Yeah, actually, it should be 0. I'll update that. And yes, I thought I could do a better job explaining, but I would prefer to keep the visuals, I think it makes the question seem more inviting. I can definitely change the visuals though, for an easier-to-understand task.

Comment: The visuals also work for the graph theoretic explanation. But only talking about general relations may be a bit to abstract (especially the Wikipedia citations) makes the task sound more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: Hmm. I thought talking about general relations would be the easiest way to go about explaining the concept. Introducing cycles and more complicated topics seemed unnecessary. How would you recommend I go about simplifying my question?

Comment: I think I'm going to leave the technical definitions in, but also provide a link to a website that explains transitive closure in simple terms. It's not very complicated at all.

Answer (score 3):

## Efficient Ouroboros Quine

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

An ouroborus quine is a program that (taking no input) outputs the source code of a different program, which in turn outputs the source code of a different program, and so on, until after some number of iterations, the result is the source code of the original program. In some cases (often called quine relays) each program is in a different language, but here all the programs forming an ouroboros should be in the same language. Let the period of an ouroboros quine, \$T\$, be the number of distinct programs involved in the loop.

The challenge is to find the most efficient ouroboros quine, achieving the maximum period using the minimum program size. Let the size, \$N\$, be the number of **bits** (not bytes) in the source code of largest program in the ouroboros. Your score is \$\frac{\log_2 T}{N}\$.

This formula is scaled such that the theoretical maximum score is arbitrarily close to 2, for arbitrarily large \$N\$. A score of 1 is achieved if every possible string of length \$N\$ is a valid program which forms a part of an ouroboros quine. The maximum theoretical score also requires that every possible string of length less than \$N\$ is a program forming part of the ouroboros.

As achieving an arbitrarily high score may require an arbitrarily large program, it is permitted to describe the program (and prove/demonstrate its correctness), rather than providing an arbitrarily large amount of raw code.

### Sandbox Questions

- Is this an interesting (and novel) question?
- Do I need to specify the output format more precisely, or do standard guidelines on output format suffice?
- Is allowing a program description, rather than raw code, a disastrous idea? Or, conversely, is it even necessary to state that this is permitted?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and very nice first challenge idea! I don't think you need to explicitly state that a description and proof for large programs is allowed (that's usually the default here). [See some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35802/114446) [Unary answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35807/114446) [which do](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53592/114446) [exactly that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67828/114446).

Answer (score 3):

## [Is this set laminar?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263627/is-this-set-laminar)

Comment: Maybe add plain English explanations alongside the mathy-notation?

Answer (score 3):

### Cut a Pizza into infinite number of slices using the minimum number of cuts

It is well known that with `n` straight cuts it is possible to cut a circle into \$\frac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}\$ pieces. This is known as the [Lazy Caterer's Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence).

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence#/media/File:Central_polygonal_numbers.svg]

However, finding the right angles to cut the circle is less easy. The areas after each cut become very small.

Your task is to find these angles. Output a infinite sequence of pairs of angles such that if you connect each pair by a line, you'd cut the circle into \$\frac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}\$ pieces. Angles may be either in degrees, radians, or any other reasonable way to measure angles, can be either floating points, fractions, or any other reasonable way to represent numbers.

As with standard sequence rules, you may:

1. Print the pairs infinitely
2. Take an input N then output the Nth chord
3. Take an input N then output the first N chords.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins.

Comment: Nice challenge, a couple of test cases would definitely help when you get the chance.

Comment: @noodleman There are many possible solutions though

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't understand this quite right. Is this not a regular sequence? Is it an [tag:open-ended-function] or something? I guess I need some kind of example to understand this.

Comment: As long as your chords divide  the circle into the required number of segments your solution is valid

Comment: Even with there being many possible solutions I think a clear example of some valid IO is worthwhile. Even just labelling the existing diagram with its angles would make things a lot easier to understand in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

## Write a Tank AI

## Preamble

This preamble will be removed in the real post.

I have created a platform to automatically run multi-language KotH. In this example, the framework will simulate an abstract battle of tanks on a grid. Each user's answer will control their tank.

The idea is that the competition will be open for a month -- after which the competition will be run offline and then the results will be appended to the Code Golf question.

I have written the [proof-of-concept simulator](https://gitlab.com/lordratte/harmagedon) in a way that makes it easy for people to add new competitions. It should be good enough for this first competition and then made more robust afterwards.

The title for the software is Harmagedon (which means Mount Magiddoh) because:

1. it conveys the idea of Armageddon i.e. there is a high stakes battle.
2. the mountain part gives a nod to classic King of the Hill type games.

I am interested in feedback on how the post can be worded more clearly and what information needs to be added.

## Tank Battle

Write an AI to control a tank on a grid. Each player's tank is placed in a randomly, unique row and column. The number of the grid's rows and columns are each equal to the number of players.

The grid is a torus. In other words, things exiting the grid from the right-most column will appear on the left-most column (in the same row), things exiting from the upper-most row will appear on the bottom most row (in the same column), and visa-versa.

Tanks receive instructions based on the output of their code. Output is in the form of two letters and a new line.

All tanks act simultaneously in a round of decision-making called a tick.

### Running code

Every tick, when the simulator needs a tank to make a decision, it runs the tank's code (passing the game state into the standard input). It then captures the standard output and performs that action (as long as it matches a valid instruction for moving or shooting).

There is a 3 second timeout for running code. Any code that takes longer to run will result in that tank not performing any action that tick.

Note: During a tick, all of the move actions will first resolve and then all of the shooting actions.

#### Format of Standard Input

The format of the game state will be as follows:

```
Game_State ::= YourUserID ';' GridWidth (';' Position)+

Position ::= TankUserID ',' XCoord ',' YCoord
```

As an example, if you are user 9999 on Code Golf Stack Exchange, and the following is the starting grid:

```
    Y
    ^
    |
    +--------+--------+--------+
    |        |        |        |
 2  |  [0]   |        |        |
    |        |        |        |
    +--------+--------+--------+
    |        |        |        |
 1  |        |        | [9999] |
    |        |        |        |
    +--------+--------+--------+
    |        |        |        |
 0  |        |[50000] |        |
    |        |        |        |
    +--------+--------+--------+-> X
        0        1        2
```

Then the input to your code will look like this for the 1st tick:

`9999;3;0,0,2;9999,2,1;50000,1,0`

Breaking it up one chunk at a time:

- `9999`: You are tank 9999.
- `3`: The grid is 3 squares wide and 3 squares tall.
- `0,0,2`: The tank controlled by user 0 is at co-ordinate (0, 2)
- `9999,2,1`: The tank controlled by user 9999 is at co-ordinate (2, 1)
- `50000,1,0`: The tank controlled by user 50000 is at co-ordinate (1, 0)

#### Format of code output

Your output can be either a moving or shooting instruction.

##### Moving Instruction

- `mu`: Move one tile up
- `md`: Move one tile down
- `ml`: Move one tile left
- `mr`: Move one tile right

If more than one tank attempts to move to the same square in a tick, only one will move there and the others will remain where they were. No grantees are made about which ones stay behind (i.e. in theory non-deterministic but potentially deterministic in implementation).

##### Shooting Instruction

- `su`: Shoot upward
- `sd`: Shoot downward
- `sl`: Shoot left
- `sr`: Shoot right

When a tank shoots in a direction, the projectile will instantly traverse from the tank in that direction until it reaches another tank or back to its starting position. If it reaches another tank (other than the one who fired it), it will destroy that tank and remove it from the grid. If no other tanks are encountered along its path, nothing happens.

### Winning

Players are ordered by the amount of time that they last on the grid. The winner is the player who doesn't die, the second placed players are those whose tanks were destroyed last, the third place are those whose tanks were destroyed second-last and so on.

Ties for places happen when more than one tank is destroyed in a tick.

### Submitting

Code should be submitted as an answer on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

The answer needs to have a very specific format so that the simulator can parse it.

The format can be described as follows.

The answer must contain at least two code blocks. The first code block should be the name of the language being used and the second should be the code being submitted.

The language can be any listed in [this JSON object](https://tio.run/languages.json). Use one of the object keys to refer to which language you will use.

Note: There is a hard 1024 character limit for submissions.

#### Example

````
# This is an example submission

All of this text before the next code block will be ignored:

```
python3
```

The above code block will be parsed to find out which language to run the code in (because it's the first code block); this text, however, will be ignored because it is not a code block.

The next code block will be parsed to get the code that will control this answer's tank. Normally one could add extra information here to elaborate on the solution.

```
import random  
stdin = input()  # Get the world state
                               
# Parse the world state
my_id, width, *tanks = stdin.split(';') 
tanks = [t.split(',') for t in tanks]          
                                               
# Get my position
my_x, my_y = next(t for t in tanks if t[0] == my_id)[1:]  
        
# Get a list of other tanks that are in-line with me
inline = [t for t in tanks if t[0] != my_id and (t[1] == my_x or t[2] == my_y)]  

if inline:      
    # If one exists,
    other_tank = inline[0]
    # then shoot on that axis.
    if other_tank[1] == my_x:
        print('sl')
    else:       
        print('su')
else:           
    # otherwise, move in a random direction
    print(random.choice(['mu', 'md', 'ml', 'mr']))
```

Everything after this previous code block will be ignored (including other `code blocks`).
````

Comment: Everything else aside for now: Do you need a separate code block to specify the language? You can indicate the language on the same line as the opening backticks.

Comment: Looks interesting, although I don't understand yet how it differs from [tag:king-of-the-hill] challenges, going to have to read it a few more times. I see you're allowing [any language on TIO](https://gitlab.com/lordratte/harmagedon/-/blob/master/tools.py?ref_type=heads#L17). Does that mean they'll all be run by making requests to TIO? Or are you planning to install languages onto your computer as necessary?

Comment: My bad, I see now you're making requests to TIO. Any idea if you'd get rate-limited or something?

Comment: @user Perhaps its not too different to KotH. It it could be a new way to do it. Since you can run more languages than the average KotH challenge and there is less manual work. I don't particularly mind if a new challenge type is created or not.

As for the TIO question. I asked the maintainer in 2021 if it's fine (back when I first had the idea) and they said that they didn't currently have plans to rate limit. Either way, when the competition is actually run, it can be done in stages if needed.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Not really. It seemed easier to explain the code blocks like this conceptually. It can always change.

Comment: Can submissions store state between ticks? When I first read this I thought the programs would be run once with stdin being blocked between ticks, but now that I know it's being run on TIO, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: This isn't a new challenge type at all, it 100% fits within [tag:king-of-the-hill]

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Fair enough. I have updated the question regarding that.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Code is run statelessly. Every time someone's code is run, the world state is passed in as input. Can you suggest a way to make it clearer?

Answer (score 3):

## Calculate the aspect ratio of the Nepal flag

[image: This is the nepal flag.]

Apove is the picture of the flag of the country Nepal. Pretty cool.

What's cooler, is the aspect ratio, which is defined under the constitution as:

[image: Aspect ratio.]

This is [A230582](https://oeis.org/A230582).

Your task is to output at least the first 113 digits of the decimal expansion, in any format of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

## Pennies to Dollars

Over on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121834/74193), [Hermant Agarwal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57212/hemant-agarwal) proposes the following question:

> In a certain country the following coins are in circulation: 1 cent, 2 cents, 5 cents, 10 cents, 20 cents, 50 cents, and 1 dollar. It is known that you can pay A cents with B coins. Prove that you can pay B dollars with A coins.

Let's help answer this! Spoilers for the answer to the puzzle below

---

> The answer relies on the fact that you can replace 1 coin worth \$X\$ cents with \$X\$ coins worth 1 dollar. For example, in the puzzle posed in the question, we replace a 20¢ coin with 20 5¢ coins.

Given a list of cent coin values \$L\$, and a positive integer \$B\$, output a positive integer \$A\$ such that

- There is a sublist of \$L\$ containing \$B\$ (not necessarily distinct) values that sum to \$A\$, and
- there is a sublist of \$L\$ containing \$A\$ (not necessarily distinct) values that sum to \$100B\$

For example, take \$L = \{2, 5, 10\}\$ and \$B = 3\$. We can see that the sublist \$\{10, 10, 10\}\$ sums to \$A = 30\$, and the sublist consisting of \$30\$ \$10\$s sums to \$300 = 100B\$. However, while there exists a sublist that sums to \$A = 6\$ with \$B = 3\$ elements, there is no sublist with \$6\$ elements that sums to \$300\$ - the maximum being \$60\$.

Another example, take \$L = \{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100\}\$ (i.e. the example in the question) and \$B = 2\$. We can make \$A = 25\$ cents with 2 coins (\$\{20, 5\}\$) and \$$2\$ with \$25\$ coins (15 \$10¢\$ and 10 \$5¢\$ coins). In this case, however, any value we choose for \$A\$ has a solution, so any positive integer is a valid output

Finally, take \$L = \{2, 5, 7\}\$ and \$B = 2\$. The possible values for \$A\$ (i.e. totals you can make with 2 coins) are \$4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14\$. However, for each of these \$A\$ values, we can see that there are no sublists of \$L\$ with \$A\$ values that sum to 200: in fact, the largest sum we can get is \$98\$. You aren't expected to handle these inputs

---

The list \$L\$ will always be non-empty, and contain positive integers between \$1\$ and \$100\$ inclusive. You may assume that, for the provided \$L\$ and \$B\$, there exists at least one \$A\$ that satisfies the conditions, and you may output any such \$A\$.

You may input and output in any [convenient manner](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833). This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

#### Test cases

*Coming soon*

Answer (score 3):

## Braille Base64

Make a one-to-one map from the base64 character table(0-9a-zA-Z+/) to Braille(U+2800-U+283F).

These characters are fixed map for compatibility. For other characters you can choose any map as long as there's no collision.

```
⠁ a     ⠃ b     ⠉ c     ⠙ d     ⠑ e     ⠋ f 
⠛ g     ⠓ h     ⠊ i     ⠚ j     ⠅ k     ⠇ l
⠍ m     ⠝ n     ⠕ o     ⠏ p     ⠟ q     ⠗ r
⠎ s     ⠞ t     ⠥ u     ⠧ v     ⠺ w     ⠭ x
⠽ y     ⠵ z     ⠴ 0     ⠂ 1     ⠆ 2     ⠒ 3
⠲ 4     ⠢ 5     ⠖ 6     ⠶ 7     ⠦ 8     ⠔ 9
```

Shortest code wins.

---

- [Braille ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII) defines uppercase letters while [Computer Braille Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Braille_Code) defines lowercase ones. Should I allow only one or both?
- Should I also fix `/` == `⠌` as the several standards all claim so?

Answer (score 3):

## Count N-Rich Permutations of an Integer Sequence

Given a sequence of integers with length \$L\$ and an integer \$1 \le N \le L\$, an "\$N\$-rich" permutation is one whose the longest **strictly** increasing subsequence has length exactly \$N\$.

For example, let our sequence be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. There is exactly one \$1\$-rich permutation, given by `[3, 2, 1, 0]`. By contrast, there are sixteen \$2\$-rich permutations:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3] [0, 3, 1, 2] [0, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 3, 2] [1, 2, 0, 3] [1, 3, 0, 2] [1, 3, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 3, 1] [2, 1, 0, 3] [2, 1, 3, 0] [2, 3, 0, 1] [2, 3, 1, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 1] [3, 1, 0, 2] [3, 1, 2, 0] [3, 2, 0, 1]
```

Note that `[0, 1, 3, 2]` is \$3\$-rich and NOT \$2\$-rich, because even though it contains a strictly increasing subsequence of length 2, it also contains a *longer* strictly increasing subsequence.

### The Challenge

Your challenge is to write a function which takes in an integer sequence S with some length \$L\$, and an integer \$1 \le N \le L\$, and returns the number of N-rich permutations of S.

This is code golf, so the shortest valid answer wins.

### Test cases

Each row is a sequence along with the expected output for all possible values of L. For example, the first row says that if your function is called `f`, then `f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) = 41`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] => 1, 69, 41, 8, 1
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] => 4, 2612, 2064, 336, 24, 0, 0
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] => 5040, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4] => 8, 2976, 1864, 192, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## Could it be a possible chess move?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

### Backstory

Professor Chesster has a library of chess puzzles with solutions, but a meteor has struck (not real, I promise) and now their hard drive may be corrupted! Luckily, Professor Chesster's puzzle FENs are stored securely, but the solutions to those puzzles have all been jumbled up and could be as ridiculous as `gxm9=L` or even `axc3`! Professer Chesster needs a quick and simple scan to check if the solutions to their puzzles are valid.

Luckily, most of the meteor is not radioactive (no [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening)) but because Professor Chesster's hard drive is now a literal potato, they need the code to be as short as possible ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)) or it might overheat!

### Stop waffling pls and show me the challenge!!!

OK, fine. Here:

Check if a move inputted with [algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) could be valid. Return a truthy value if it is, and a falsy value otherwise.

### List of all moves that are valid

```
Na1, Na2, ..., Nh8
Ka1, ...
... [all other pieces]
Nxa1, Nxa2, ... [captures]
Nba1, ... [specify row]
N2a1, ... [specify col]
Nb3a1, ... [row & col]
Nbxa1, N2xa1, Nb3xa1, ...
(NOT Kab3 as there's only one king)
O-O (or 0-0??? META - WHAT DO I DO)
O-O-O (or 0-0-0??? META - THIS TOO)
axb2 to axb7
bxc2 to bxc7
...
gxh2 to gxh7
then bxa1 to bxa7 ... hxg7
Then promotions (a1=Q, a1=R, a1=B, a1=N)
b1=QRBN, c1=QRBN, ..., h1=QRBN
a8=QRBN, ...
axb1=QRBN,bxc1=QRBN, .......
[other moves I may have missed]
```

### Scoring

Again, Professor Chesster's hard drive is such a potato that they require it to be golfed as much as possible. (this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf))

### META: Mandatory duplicate check

Not a duplicate of [Is it a valid chess move?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148587/is-it-a-valid-chess-move) as that asks about a specific position.

Not a duplicate of [Is it a plausible chess move?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/is-it-a-plausible-chess-move) as that doesn't include piece information and a few other things that will be mentioned below

### Sandbox/Meta stuff

- Specifications

  - Do I include...

    - Check (`move+`)?
    - Double check (`move++`)?
    - Checkmate (`move#`)?
  - **Did I miss any other chess moves?**
- Funny enough backstory?

Comment: Are we allowed to move our king into check?

Comment: related challenges: [next move in restricted set of moves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10843/chess-find-all-legal-moves-except-castling-and-en-passant),  [verify next move](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148587/is-it-a-valid-chess-move)

Comment: @bsoelch If I'm reading it correctly it's about outputting all possible moves from any position. So something like `axc6` would not be included in the output because no matter what the position is, a pawn can't take a piece two files away from it. I could be misinterpreting the question though, it certainly isn't too clear what is meant by "all valid chess moves."

Comment: It's all moves that could ever be valid in any position. Editing that in now

Comment: Considering that the order of possible moves is not fixed I would not mark it as `sequence`

Comment: You should probably explain/link to the chess notation you are using

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer doesn't matter as it's over all possible boards || @bsoelch thanks for related challenges; not marked `sequence` anymore; linked to algebraic notation || @AidenChow yes - see the updated question

Comment: IMO you would need to specify how to differentiate a a good move from a brilliant move from a normal move (Sotckfish uses an AI and an specific scoring system to determine the quality of a move)

Comment: You don't need to differentiate them; this program has no input. It generates ALL possible moves from ALL possible boards

Answer (score 3):

### [Decode Chess Move](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264562/78039)

Comment: Apart from exluding moves like Nae5 (which I assume you did intentionally - "Knight (b) to a3" or "Knight(b) to a3" seem like good options if you were to include it) this looks good. May want to specify how to handle O-O-O (using the letter o and not the number 0)

Comment: @WD for ambiguous moves (such as Nae5 even tho that is not a valid move) input will specify the starting square and the target square. For example, imagine there is a knight on d3 and another one on f3, input will specify the movement of the d3 knight as `Nd3e5`

Answer (score 3):

## A robber flipped some bits. This is what happened to the cop's code. [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

### Objective

Cops shall pose a code that outputs a truthy or falsy value **deterministically**, depending on the input. The output must be truthy on some inputs **and** falsy on some other inputs.

Flipping some **bits** in the code shall result in negating the output for every input. Robbers shall find such bits.

### Winning criterion

For cops, the submission whose the **cardinality** of all valid inputs is the biggest shall win. The shortness of the code is a tiebreaker. In other words, this is primarily [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) and secondarily [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). (Note that there may be infinitely many valid inputs, and its cardinality cannot exceed aleph-naught.)

For robbers, the submission whose percentage of the flipped bits is the closest to 50% shall win. The number of the flipped bits is a tiebreaker. So this is primarily [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) and secondarily [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling).

### Rule

Cops must specify what the valid inputs are.

Comment: I think you should elaborate the 'cardinality of valid inputs' scoring criterion better.  In Husk, a cop answer could be ```→``` = increment.  All integers are valid inputs (so they are infinite), and only ```-1``` results in falsy output (zero).    I don't think there's a single-byte Husk command that would make ```-1``` truthy and everything else falsy, so it seems uncrackable.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen they way I understood the second sentence of the objective, there has to be a way to crack the program for the submission to be valid

Comment: @bsoelch - ah, that makes sense…

Comment: Why is higher cardinality better?  I would think it would be the opposite.

Comment: @WheatWizard If smaller cardinality were better, cop submissions might take no input, which gives cardinality 1. That's too trivial.

Comment: Isn't trivial better?  It makes it harder to disguise things.  But if trivial is bad what's to prevent someone from "taking" the input and ignoring it.  That makes no real difference to the cop but makes their score in that infinity.

Answer (score 3):

## What's my score?

The question score on Stack Exchange is the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes a question receives. However, the reputation gained/lost for every upvote/downvote is different (10/-2 on Code Golf).

Given the total reputation and the reputation gained/lost on votes, list out all possible scores the question could have.

### Rules

- The total reputation, the reputation gained by an upvote and reputation lost by a downvote must be integers
- The upvote-reputation will be positive and the downvote-reputation will be negative
- You can output the possible question scores as a (possibly infinite) list or print each one individually.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins

### Examples

```
[total reputation, upvote-reputation, downvote-reputation] -> [question scores]

[28, 10, -2]  -> [2, -2, -6, -10, ...]
[34, 10, -2]  -> [1, -3, -7, -11, ...]
[17, 10, -2]  -> []
[11, 7, -5]   -> [1, -1, -3, -5, ...]
[82, 31, -11] -> [2, -18, -38, -58, ...]
[15, 5, -10]  -> [3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Sum of consecutive nth powers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264918/119451) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Answer (score 3):

## [How many ways to cut a number into an equation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265117/how-many-ways-to-cut-a-number-into-an-equation)

Answer (score 3):

## [Play a game of memory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265307/play-a-game-of-memory)

Comment: Suggest test case "cbxcxvbaav", 8

Comment: @mathscat Added, thank you.

Comment: @bsoelch In Memory you pick the cards in order, so you can adjust the second card based on the first, so if you see the first has a match you can choose that match as the second card

Answer (score 3):

## [Numbers with distinct decimal digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265310/numbers-with-distinct-decimal-digits)

Answer (score 3):

## [The multiples are missing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265776/the-multiples-are-missing)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Answer (score 3):

## [Do you win a Numeric Mahjong?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265480/78410)

Comment: why do we need the first rule? That would be like restricting languages made after posting this question

Comment: @UndoneStudios Now that I think of it, fractional byte encodings seem fine. Variable length encodings (like Vyncode) are a problem, because they don't really define a mapping from a char in source to an integer.

Comment: This should be a question to raise in meta

Comment: @UndoneStudios The rule is needed to define how to convert a source code to a list of integers. It totally isn't like "restricting languages made after posting this question". All languages can participate as long as they have a textual or byte representation (which practically all languages used on the site do). Only some *encodings* of some languages are not allowed.

Comment: Well, technically, I was only against variable encodings; that is cheaty

Answer (score 3):

## [Implement Subleq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265424/implement-subleq)

Comment: @bsoelch Fixed.

Comment: @bsoelch That was a mistake on my part as well, I'll replace the example.

Answer (score 3):

Find the k-th largest number

Given the string representation of three sorted lists, get the k-th largest number.

The string representation has such form:

```
1 3 5 7 11 120 9988
23 68 99 111
107 131 888
```

aka. lists are separated by newline `\n` and numbers in one list are separated by space.

Length of each list, length of the string and k are directly given, but access to the string costs. You can fetch from a given position. Least fetches wins.

Your solution should handle all possible inputs well, but only optimize score for average cases.

[This](https://tio.run/##VVBdb4IwFH3nV9w32oAo4DZMxxKSPe9pb26JBStUsDVtMVkWfzu7dWq2Nqfp/Tr33LvnJ24bI49upvRWTK/VewUlbNLHDIriCdJltgryHFYZpAWeIM1yQCwvz8OGBTvhmk5YLFqgMarGSa3g4iWSwncAEEXXJIaGEW40CnyjtfxkwTlotLJ6EMmgW9K7juSxvz4hGYRqXRenlLJ/abemEYRw/YeUTff2nkbxGFSNaGJAnhj6XzUnbsDLrYzhXwQj1MvaaQPEh2S5YCCf0c9Q@HUCAItiseg2ly85IzyRTfZaKhKGNDlwH55/bKN5660jeRsPtTA0sdo4Qnhc0/KFz2r6ZxV23fs9TNMP) is an example solution. It solves the problem with an awful score, but you can also use lib here. Write the lib if it's absent in your language.

---

Sorted lists in test cases will be generated in this way:

- Generate 1 million (1'000'000) integers uniformly in \$\left[0, 2^{31}-1\right]\$. Duplicates will likely appear.
- Sort them.

[Not decided yet] It's fine if your code is only optimized for three 1M length arrays and fallback to worst solution for other input.

Comment: You should clarify what "average case" means. From what distribution are the inputs taken? Additionally, can there be duplicates in the lists?

Comment: @CommandMaster Added

Answer (score 3):

## [I (rev)?(pal)? the source code, you (rev)?(pal)? the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265514/78410)

Answer (score 3):

## Complete an equivalence relation

In set theory, a *relation* from a set \$A\$ to a set \$B\$ is a set of pairs of elements from \$A\$ and \$B\$. For example, \$\{(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)\}\$ is a relation  from the set \$\{1, 2, 3\}\$ to the set \$\{4, 5, 6\}\$.

A relation \$R\$ from a set \$A\$ to itself is an *equivalence relation* iff:

- It is *reflexive*: For all elements of \$A\$, \$(a, a)\$ is in \$R\$.
- It is *symmetric*: If a pair \$(a, b)\$ is in \$R\$, then so is \$(b, a)\$.
- It is *transitive*: If the pairs \$(a, b)\$ and \$(b, c)\$ are in \$R\$, then so is \$(a, c)\$.

For example, \$\{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)\}\$ is an equivalence relation on the set \$\{1, 2, 3\}\$.

Your challenge is to, given a relation from a set to itself, add as few pairs of elements as possible to transform it into an equivalence relation.

### Worked example

If we start with the relation \$\{(1, 2), (3, 2), (4, 4)\}\$, then:

Firstly, the relation must be reflexive, so all pairs of elements \$(a, a)\$ must be added, resulting in \$\{(1, 2), (3, 2), (4, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)\}\$.

Next, the relation must be symmetric, so we need to add the inverses of \$(1, 2)\$ and \$(3, 2)\$, resulting in \$\{(1, 2), (3, 2), (4, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3)\}\$.

Finally, the relation must be transitive. Since \$(1, 2)\$ and \$(2, 3)\$ are in the relation, so must be \$(1, 3)\$, and likewise \$(3, 1)\$ must also be in the relation. Adding these results in \$\{(1, 2), (3, 2), (4, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 1)\}\$, and this is an equivalence relation.

Input/output is can be lists of pairs of positive integers, or an adjacency matrix. You can optionally take the domain of the relation (i.e. all unique values in it). The order in which you output the pairs does not matter, and you can assume the input will be nonempty.

### Testcases

```
{(1, 1)} -> {(1, 1)}
{(1, 2)} -> {(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1)}
{(1, 2), (3, 4)} -> {(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 3)}
{(1, 2), (1, 3)} -> {(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)}
{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)} -> {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)}
{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4)} -> {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3)}
{(1, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1)} -> {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)}
{(8, 19), (4, 12), (9, 31), (4, 18)} -> {(8, 8), (8, 19), (19, 8), (19, 19), (4, 4), (4, 12), (4, 18), (12, 4), (12, 12), (12, 18), (18, 4), (18, 12), (18, 18), (9, 9), (9, 31), (31, 9), (31, 31)}
{(8, 7), (2, 7), (14, 3), (3, 16)} -> {(2, 2), (2, 7), (2, 8), (7, 2), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 2), (8, 7), (8, 8), (3, 3), (3, 14), (3, 16), (14, 3), (14, 14), (14, 16), (16, 3), (16, 14), (16, 16)}
{(1, 1), (1, 2)} -> {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)}
```

Comment: Could output be loosened to not require outputting pairs already in the input? Although for some reason I feel iffy about going in between, i.e. allowing the output to contain some input pairs without requiring it to contain all of them...

Comment: @UnrelatedString What exactly are you thinking of when you say that? I can't think of any reasonable approach which would necessitate that. Besides, the point of the challenge is to create the minimal superset that's an equivalence relation.

Comment: I was mostly inspired by the phrase "add as few pairs of elements as possible"--thinking about the interplay between symmetry and transitivity, it seems unlikely any solution would actually benefit from only outputting the added pairs, which makes me kinda curious about leaving the option open.

Comment: Do you have to deduce the set or can you take it as input? Can you use adjacency matrices? Can you output the equivalence classes?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263566/calculating-transitive-closure)

Comment: @CommandMaster I'll allow taking the domain as input, and I/O as adjacency matrices. I'm not going to allow outputting the equivalence classes because I can think of several approaches that wouldn't even compute them and I want things to stay semiconsistent. I don't think this is a dupe for two reasons: one, that challenge requires outputting the _number_ of sets to add which a lot of answers take advantage of; two, while transitivity is the hard part of this challenge, incorporating reflexivity and symmetry into an answer from there is still nontrivial.

Comment: are delimiters required? or can i take `{(1, 2), (3, 4)}` as `1 2 3 4` and output `1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 4 3 3 4 4 4 3`?

Comment: @thejonymyster Since it's a list of pairs, sure, that's fine. I believe taking a flattened list is in the I/O defaults anyway

Answer (score 3):

[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)? [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)? [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)?

### Golfy Fairy Chess Notation + Validation

#### Step 1:

Design an encoding for fairy chess piece movement which encodes all of the following information:

- Where a piece can move (INCLUDING arbitrary length movement)*
- Whether those movements are "jumping" or not
- Whether those movements are "capturing" or not**

You don't need to handle non-moving, royalty, special case movement (such as first move double-movement), or any other special stuff like that.

#### Step 2:

Write a program which, when given (A):

- a chess position***
- a starting square
- an ending square

all in any reasonable format of your choice, as well as (B):

- a description of a fairy chess piece's movement capabilities
  in the notation you designed in step 1

will output whether the movement on the board (A) is valid for that fairy chess piece (B)

#### Additional spec clarification

You may assume

- All pieces other than the piece being moved are pawns
- The fairy chess piece is the piece that will be moved
- The fairy chess piece movement will be defined such that it could theoretically make a move, given the right board arrangement (i.e. no 'non-movers')
- Movement will be entirely within the board
- Board will be square and at least 2x2 in size
- Piece will not attempt to capture its own teammates
- Piece will not attempt to move to its own square, and you don't need to worry about whether the notation implies it should/shouldn't be able to.

You may *not* assume an 8x8 board.

#### Scoring:****

\$(\text{bytes in program})\times(\text{average bytes to represent each piece in (list of fairy chess pieces which will be provided)})\$

Lowest score wins

Optional challenge: try and make the format human legible! :-)

#### META:

*I will be sure to clarify in the question body how exactly this works; but basically i want to be able to include things like rook/bishop/queen/knightrider without having to assume a maximum movement distance

**I'll also be clear that pieces can only capture at the *end* of their move, so no multicapture or capture and then move / en passant nonsense :P

***I don't know how to explain, but this doesnt have to include which pieces are what. just where the pieces are and whether each piece is on your team or not, or something similarly simple

****Ideally, score would be based on both short notation as well as a short decoding program, but I'm not sure the exact balance yet. feel free to tell me this is a bad idea / throw your algo of choice at me, but i'll be studying other compression challenges as well

Comment: Heads up: It looks like the bullet-point formatting in the first list under step 2 is wrong (missing newlines?).

Comment: @SuperStormer great catch, that wouldve taken forever for me to notice lol thank you

Answer (score 3):

## [Minecraft XP Orb Amounts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266158/minecraft-xp-orb-amounts)

Answer (score 3):

## Make Code Printing X without X

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

The challenge is simple: write a program which takes in some string \$n\$ consisting of only uppercase and lowercase letters, and outputs the *code* for a program (in the same language) which takes in no input and outputs \$n\$. However, the code your program generates *must not have any of the characters of \$n\$*. For example, if your program was in Python, if the input was `"Lit"`, your output could not be `print("Lit")`, because that contains `L`, `i`, and `t`. One valid output would be, for example, `x=lambda:'\114\151\164'`.

Some notes:

- Uppercase and lowercase characters are treated as distinct -- e.g. if the input string contains `A`, your generated code can still contain the character `a`.
- Your generated code follows the same restrictions as a standard code golf answer -- e.g. it can be code which defines an anonymous function returning the string, but it cannot work by saving the string into a variable.
- Your submission is scored by the length of the *generating* code, not the *generated* code. In addition, there are no restrictions on the source of the generating program, only the generated.

Standard loopholes are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

### Questions

I don't know what to call this challenge.

Comment: [tag:code-generation]

Comment: Because of the possibility that input contains all letters, all answers would likely never output letters

Comment: @l4m2 Hm.... I somehow didn't think of that; that means this challenge isn't possible in many languages. I could add a limit on the number of distinct characters which can occur in the input, but that feels inelegant. Other thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

## Is it a valid crossword grid?

In crossword terminology, the grid is the region into which the crossword answers are inserted, consisting of white and black squares. The crossword answers, called entries, are inserted into contiguous sequences of white squares in a row or column, separated by black squares.

For British (and Commonwealth) crosswords, the grids usually follow a specific set of rules:

- They should have 180 degree rotational symmetry (if there is a black
  square in the xth row and yth column, there should be a black square
  in the xth-to-last row and y th-to-last column).
- No entries may be exactly two squares long.
- All white squares must be joined in a single region.
- No row/column can be completely filled with black squares.
- Each two-by-two square must contain at least one white square.
- Each two-by-three rectangle must contain at least one black square.

For `n=3` there is only one valid grid (I'm using `.` for white squares and `#` for black squares):

```
...
.#.
...
```

For `n=4` there are no valid grids, although British crosswords usually use odd `n` anyway.

Here are some examples of valid grids for `n=5`:

```
.....  .....  #.#.#  ###.#
.#.#.  .###.  .....  #....
.....  .....  #.#.#  #.#.#
.#.#.  .###.  .....  ....#
.....  .....  #.#.#  #.###
```

Here are two examples of valid grids for `n=6`:

```
......  ......
.##.#.  .##.#.
.#....  ....#.
....#.  .#....
.#.##.  .#.##.
......  ......
```

Input may be in the form of an array of any two byte-sized values and output can be any two distinct values of your choice or any of your language's truthy or falsy values respectively.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: .................... :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge Comment Outline Creator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266152/)

Comment: Is it equivalent to a 0-1 matrix with an even sum in each row/column? Additionally, I'm assuming an all-space answer is invalid, but I don't see any rule disallowing it. Could you add one?

Comment: @CommandMaster Almost, however having no semicolons at all would result in the IP reading in the comment as code. I could probably clarify that.

Comment: Can I take as input `w+2, h+2` instead of `w, h`?

Comment: @CommandMaster Is it too expensive to add 2 to the inputs?

Comment: I haven't tried, and `w, h` might be shorter, but it might be easier to use the size of the output instead of the size of the comment itself

Comment: @CommandMaster Hm, I may consider it, it doesn't seem like it would be unfair

Answer (score 3):

## Intersections in a Circular Scrambled Word

Given a word `W` and a scrambled version of it `S` as input, you are required to return the number of intersections `S` will have when organized in a circular arrangement.

## Example

Let `W` be `VICTORY` and `S` be `VICYTRO`. After transforming the scrambled word in its circular form and forming the original word by adding segments between the characters, we have the following diagram:

[image]

As we can see, for this particular example, the expected output is `2` interceptions.

## Specs

- Input will consist only of `[A-Z]` characters.
- It is irrelevant how you set up the circular word (clockwise, counterclockwise, if the characters are evenly spaced from one another or not), just be consistent.
- Input is flexible, read it however you see fit for you.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

## Test Cases

```
Format: 
W , S  --> output

VICTORY, VICYTRO --> 2
# To be added more
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answers in bytes wins!

## Meta

Is the challenge interesting? Is there anything unclear? I am not a native English speaker, so I welcome any corrections on the wording of the challenge.

I will later add more test cases. Also, what is the general consensus here where there are multiple correct answers? Because when I add words with repeated letters, depending on the "path" you choose when forming the circular word, it will affect the number of intersections. (I'll update the specs section as well when I introduce these special cases).

Lastly, I didn't give much thought on my second point in the specs section, maybe it's wrong... I'll observe more cases later.

Pretty much any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Could take input as a permutation of 1..n, to get rid of worrying about repeated letter ambiguity as well as some potential for a "chameleon challenge" (i.e. determining the permutation between the two words could be highly nontrivial in some languages and overshadow the actual "core" of intersections between circle chords). If you do want solutions to have to handle repeats, then I'd recommend just allowing them to give any of the possible outputs.

Comment: re. multiple possible outputs: challenges often specify that submissions may choose to either output all possible outputs or just one of them.

Comment: I suggest to write **W** and **S** instead of `W` and `S` to avoid confusion, because those are just names, no data.

Answer (score 3):

## [Seat gangs as far as possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266423/seat-gangs-as-far-as-possible)

Comment: @noodleman No, the gangs can be any (non-zero) size -- \$k\$ is the number of gangs.

Comment: Suggest test case `1,2,1,2,1` -> `1,1,1,2,2`

Answer (score 3):

### Longest irreducible quine

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267486)

Comment: Would a submission be valid if it can be reduced to an improper quine, but not to a proper one?

Comment: @noodleman ty, clarified

Comment: In most languages it will be possible to make it longer by somehow splitting it, but you can't reduce it by only removing characters, but you also need to change some. I never saw a good »longest« challenge, and I doubt this will be the first.

Comment: @Philippos not quite sure how this would work, care to give an example?

Comment: @Philippos This is wrong - it easily follows from [Higman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman's_lemma) that in all languages (they don't even have to be computable!) there is only a finite number of irreducible programs which perform a given task, so in particular the length must be bounded.

Comment: @CommandMaster thanks for clarifying!

Comment: An example: You can split your example like `v='%r;print("v="+v%%v)';print("v="+v%v)` Easy to reduce, but not only by only removing bytes.

Comment: @Philippos Sure, but I don't see how this can be extended further indefinitely. (Granted, I'm not very experienced with quines/irreducible code)

Comment: You could continue like `v='%r;pront("v="+v.replace(chr(111),"i")%%v)';print("v="+v.replace(chr(111),"i")%v)`, which of course could be repeated similarly many times without possible reduction.

Comment: @CommandMaster I don't know whether Higman's lemma can be appllied here. Even if it can, the length border could be somewhere in the thousands, millions, billions ...

Comment: @Philippos I know it can be large, but that's the point of the challenge. Why couldn't it be applied? If you look at the set of all irreducible programs performing a particular task, no element of that set is a subsequence of another element, so it must be finite.

Comment: @CommandMaster Well, math scat may give it a try, but still I believe it won't be fun, because the people will lose interest before reaching any border. Or I'm wrong (rumours claim this did already happen before ;-)

Comment: @Philippos [This irreducible code bowling challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/biggest-irreducible-hello-world) was very well received, I don't see why this will be worse

Comment: @CommandMaster One look at the exponents is enough for me to walk away.

Comment: (at Phillipos and CommandMaster) thanks for your feedback, I do think I'll give this challenge a try though.

Answer (score 3):

## Calculate a struct size

In C and C++, the size of a structure depends not only on the sizes of its members but also their alignment requirements.

This problem will assume a simple case in which each structure is made up of primitive types that have a size that is a power of two and an alignment that equals their size.

Given a list of the types in a structure, please output the resulting size of the structure.

Here is an example structure:

```c
struct {
  char c[5];
  int i, j;
  short s[3];
}
```

Input in any of the following formats is acceptable:

- A list of the sizes of the individual types that make up the structure; for the above that would be `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2]`
- A list giving the lengths of each array and the sizes of its elements, which for the above would be `[[5, 1], [1, 4], [1, 4], [3, 2]]`
- A list giving the size and alignment of each variable, which for the above would be `[[5, 1], [4, 4], [4, 4], [6, 2]]`

(The third format indirectly supports nested structures but this can be emulated for the other formats by replacing them with an array of the same size and alignment.)

The size of the above structure is `24`. Here is how it is calculated:

1. Each of the `5` `char`s consumes `1` byte each, making `5`.
2. Each `int` requires an alignment of `4`, so there are three bytes of padding before the first of them. The total size is now `16`.
3. Each of the `3` `short`s consume `2` bytes each. The total size is now `22`.
4. The entire structure has an alignment of the largest alignment of any member, which in this case is `4`, so the size must be rounded up to the next multiple of `4`, which is `24`.

Visually:

```
c[0] c[1] c[2] c[3]
c[4] ..............
i__________________
j__________________
s[0]_____ s[1]_____
s[2]_____ .........
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 3):

## [Just another traffic jam!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267180/just-another-traffic-jam)

Comment: Can you specify the zip-lock system?

Comment: @Seggan I added that, thank you. I somehow thought this would be internationally known.

Answer (score 3):

## Output 5-line calendar

Given year, month and optionally weekday of 1st, output the calendar of the month.

For empty cell, fill it with the date where it's supposed to be, in last or next month, and add `#` to indicate gray. If last few days can't fit in 5 lines, then they share last line with 5th week, use `/` to separate two days.

Sample Input: `Nov 2023`

Sample Output:

```
 #28   #29   #30     1     2     3     4
   5     6     7     8     9    10    11
  12    13    14    15    16    17    18
  19    20    21    22    23    24    25
  26    27    28    29    30    #1    #2
```

Sample Input: `Dec 2023`

Sample Output:

```
 #26   #27   #28   #29   #30     1     2
   3     4     5     6     7     8     9
  10    11    12    13    14    15    16
  17    18    19    20    21    22    23
24/31   25    26    27    28    29    30
```

Outputting a 2D array of string is fine

Answer (score 3):

## [How long is this string, really?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268943/how-long-is-this-string-really)

Answer (score 3):

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

In this challenge answers will provide three elements:

- A programming language: \$L\$
- An output string: \$S\$
- And a non-empty string: \$B_n\$

You will also write, but not reveal, a program in \$L\$ which outputs \$S\$, built by concatenating copies of the \$B_n\$ strings from your answer *and previous answers* in any order.

For example here are two answers given in pseudocode:

> ### Answer 1
>
> \$S\$ = `H`
> \$B_0\$ = `print "H"`

> The program is `print "H"`

> ### Answer 2
>
> \$S\$ = `Hiiii`
> \$B_1\$ = `++"i"`

> The program is `print "H"++"i"++"i"++"i"++"i"`

Robbers will try to discover a valid solution, that is a program made from the \$B_n\$ strings in your answer and previous answers which outputs your \$S\$. Your goal will be to make this as hard as possible.

### States

As with any [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge, cops' posts here can have 4 different states:

- Vulnerable
- Cracked
- Safe
- Revealed

All cops' posts start as *vulnerable*. If a robber finds and posts a solution to a *vulnerable* post they will receive 1 point and the post will become *cracked*. If a post lasts 10 days in *vulnerable* without being solved it automatically becomes *safe*. A cop with a *safe* post may choose to reveal their program and their safe post will become *revealed*. A robber can still solve a *safe* post, if they do they receive a point and the post becomes *revealed*.

Only *revealed* posts are eligible for scoring. Robbers are only permitted to solve *vulnerable* and *safe* posts.

### Scoring

For cops' an answer's score is the number of cops' posts before it if it is *revealed* and 0 if it is any other state. The goal is to get as high a score as possible.

### Languages

In the interest of fairness, we are going to require that languages are free and reasonably cross platform. Both languages you choose must be freely available on Linux and FreeBSD (the two largest foss operating systems). This includes languages which are free and open source.

Your selected languages must predate this challenge.

Programs here should be complete programs not functions, expressions or snippets.

Comment: I wonder, would cops want to make writing challenges for future cops easier or harder? Also, your example challenges don't state the language, although the text above them says the cop ought to state it.

Comment: @CommandMaster I state both are in pseudocode.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's outside the answer quote, so this might be a bit confusing

Comment: Does the cop/robber need to use all of previous \$B_n\$? I suggest stating either way explicitly.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Can i simply repeat the Bn by 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, ... and try the connected result one by one?

Answer (score 3):

## [How many cacti can I plant here?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/272240)

Comment: Hi, I like the question a lot. I would consider either sticking to edge-wrapping or not. As it is, you should specify which behavior the test cases are for, and ideally add both sets of test cases. Also, don't forget to specify that this is a code golf question.

Comment: @chunes Thank you, I'll stick to the Minecraft template. The test cases actually differ with edge-wrapping, the third one can only contain 16 instead of 17 cacti and the fourth one 76 instead of 79.

Answer (score 2):

**Perfect Hash Generator**

Given N words you are to generate a perfect hash function (ala [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)). A perfect hash function for a set of strings is a hash function with no collisions. An additional condition is that the range of the generated hash function must be [0...O(N)] (i.e. at most a constant times larger than N). You can use any language for the generated function.

> Can we get some feedback on this old post? I'm wondering if it is possible to avoid the obvious loophole of a cat program.

Comment: Sounds good at first blush. Do you foresee this as a [code-golf] or some more extensive challenge? If the later what metric would be used to judge it? I think that evaluation of results for compliance is easy enough *if* the resulting hashes are composed into programs---in unix: `entry < testfile > hash_program && hash_program < testfile | sort -u | wc -l` and compare to `wc -l testfile`---but less obvious if the submitters don't provide a scaffold (and if they do should it be counted toward length in the event that this is a [code-golf]?).

Comment: Perl solution, 2 bytes (1, plus 1 for `-pE` instead of `-E`): `;` Or, wait, did you mean that our program has to *print another* program that generates a hash? Then `say";"` I suppose, at 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Huffman Decoding

Write a programm which takes two strings as input and prints a text.

---

The first argument is a [Huffman Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), serialized in the following format:

- every ascii character except `~` is always a leaf, if `~` is the first characater it is also a leaf.
- `<tree0><tree1>~` is a tree where `<tree0>` is the left subtree and `<tree1>` is the right subtree.

Example: `ab~cde~~~` generates this tree:

```
 ┌─┴─┐
┌┴┐ ┌┴─┐
a b c ┌┴┐
      d e
```

where `a` would have the key `00`, `b` `01`, `c` `10`, `d` `110` and `e` the key `111`.

---

The second argument is a text that has been compressed with with the Huffman code that is defined by the first parameter. This bit-string can contain any bit sequence (also null-bytes and non-printable characters) and is not byte aligned, therefore it has been encoded with a variation of the standard [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding:

- the characters used for the encoding are the standard base64 characters: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`
- the bitstring is broken up into 6-bit chunks and mapped to this characters
- if the last chunk is smaller than 6 bits, a character with this prefix is used, and padding characters are added to the string:
- `-`   : the last chunk was five bits long
- `=`   : the last chunk was four bits long
- `=-`  : the last chunk was three bits long
- `==`  : the last chunk was two bits long
- `==-` : the last chunk was one bit long

Example:

```
bits:       1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
chunks:    |1 1 1 1 0 1|1 0 1 0 0 1|1 1 0 1 0 1|0 0 0 1 1 0|1[0 0 0 0 0]|
characters:       9           p           1           G           g
base64:     9p1Gg==-
```

---

Your programm has to decode the text encoded in the second parameter and print it to stdout.

You have to provide your source code encoded in the way described above.
The length of your encoded source code + the length of your serialized huffman tree will be the winning criterion.

TODO: example input

Comment: It would be helpful to explicitly state the 64 characters used in the encoding. I presume they're `A-Za-z0-9+/` but (especially if you're expecting people to implement that part explicitly) it's best to make the problem self-contained.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 2):

### Polygon prefixes

Polygons are named after the number of sides that they have. A pentagon has 5 sides, an octagon has 8 sides. But how are they named? What's the name for a 248-sided polygon?

All polygons are suffixed with `-gon`. There are specific prefixes for each polygon depending on the number of sides. Here are the prefixes for the lower numbers:

```
3 - tri
4 - tetra
5 - penta
6 - hexa
7 - hepta
8 - octa
9 - nona
10 - deca
11 - undeca
12 - dodeca
13 - triskaideca
14 - tetradeca
15 - pentadeca
16 - hexadeca
17 - heptadeca
18 - octadeca
19 - nonadeca
20 - icosa
```

Polygons with 21 to 99 sides have a different system. Take the prefix for the tens digit (found on the left column), the ones digit (right column below), and then stick a "kai" between them to get `(tens)(ones)gon`.

```
20 - icosi       | 1 - hena
30 - triaconta   | 2 - di
40 - tetraconta  | 3 - tri
50 - pentaconta  | 4 - tetra
60 - hexaconta   | 5 - penta
70 - heptaconta  | 6 - hexa
80 - octaconta   | 7 - hepta
90 - nonaconta   | 8 - octa
                 | 9 - nona
```

The 3-digit sided polygons are named in a similar fashion. A 100-sided polygon is called a hectogon. Take the hundreds digit, find it on the column for ones digits, then stick a "hecta" to its right. Now number off the tens and ones like above: `(hundreds)hecta(tens)(ones)gon`. If the hundreds place digit is a 1, don't put the prefix behind "hecta".

So, given an integer (3 <= n <= 999), return the name of an n-sided polygon. `n-gon` is not a valid answer :P

As with all code golf, shortest code wins.

---

Is the description good? Would it be harder if I instead asked for the number of sides, given a name?

Comment: What is a 101-sided figure called? "hectahenagon"? Is "hena" from the `column for ones digits` you mention? If so, then what is a 111-sided figure called? I'd say "hectaundecagon", but then that comes from a column where "hena" is not present.

Comment: @Gaffi: Yep, it's hectahenagon, from what Google says.

Comment: I am going to take this if you allow me or if you don't respond

Answer (score 2):

### Code golfing problem: Surface classification

**The task:** Given a surface-word reply with the classification of what surface it is.

**Example 1:** Input: `aba'b'` ----> Output: `1T`

**Example 2:** Input: `aabcb'c'` ----> Output: `3P`

**Bounds on the problem:** Since there are only 26 letters, there will never be more than that many labels. Additionally output should be in the form `S`,`nT`,`mP` for `n`,`m` positive integers.

**Background:** In the study of algebraic topology students are often presented with diagrams such as the one below. The represent instructions for how to assemble a surface. The assembly is prescribed as: if there are two edges labeled with the letter `x` then glue them together so that the arrows point the same direction. To make our job easy, topologists have discovered an algorithmic way to classify surfaces using 'words' assembled from these 'plane gluing-diagrams'.

[image]
Choosing a corner arbitrarily (top right) and orientation (ccw) we read off the labels on the edges where an inverse appears wherever the arrow points against the orientation. In this case the 'word' that represents this plane model is given as `abab`.

A surface word is a string that contains the letters `a,b,...,@` up to some letter `@` and each letter is contained in it exactly twice. In the two occurrences of each letter: 0, 1, or 2 of them may be postfixed by a `'` which I am considering using to represent 'inverse' (opposite orientation).

If in a surface word all letters appear twice: once without the `'` and once with it (f.ex. `ba'b'a`) then we say that the surface the word represents is *orientable*. If a surface is orientable then it is necessarily the direct sum of `n` Tori for some non-negative integer `n`. If this condition doesn't hold (like in `aab'b`) then the surface represented is *non-orientable*: in this case it is the direct sum of `m` Projective Planes for some positive integer `m`.

Once you have found out if the reduced word is orientable or not, the final answer is given as follows. If orientable and number of unique letters in the reduced word is 1 then output should be `S`. Otherwise if the number of unique letters in an orientable word is `n` (it will be even) then the output should be `sT` where `s = n/2`. If the word is non-orientable then the output should be `mP` where `m` is the number of distinct letters in the reduced word.

The goal is to take as input some surface word, reduce it via reduction rules `1-6` and then classify it as a sphere, some number of connected tori, or some number of connected projective planes. Here are the 6 reduction rules where `~` represents 'reduces to':

Let `M,A,B,C,D` be surface words, `x` be a single letter, and juxtaposition represents concatenation:

1. *Cycle Rule:* If `M = AB` then `M ~ BA`
2. *Flip Rule:* `M ~ M'`
3. *Sphere Rule:* `Axx'B ~ AB`
4. *Block Rule:* `ABC ~ ADC` if `B` is a surface word and `B ~ D` by 1 or 2
5. *Cylinder Rule:* If `M = AxBCx'D`, then `M ~ AxCBx'D`
6. *Möbius Rule:* If `M = AxBxC` then `M ~ AxxB'C ~ AB'xxC`

I am looking for input on:

- should this be `code-golf` or `programming-challenge`?
- how would scoring work?
- ???

If I feel satisfied with the question in a few days I'll post it to the site.

Comment: If, for each input, there is only one correct output, then it should probably be code-golf.  The scoring criteria would then be source code length.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. In general however there is not a unique series of applications of the reduction rules for any given instance.

Comment: I don't think the order of explanation is correct. You should explain reduction before talking about "the reduced word". And "reduce it via reduction rules" doesn't entirely make sense, because the rules are presented as equivalences rather than reductions, and most of them don't have a "natural" direction.

Comment: It's also occurred to me that you haven't defined the notation `M'`. Does it just consist of toggling the orientation of each token, or does it also reverse the entire string? And do you have test cases which between them force implementation of all of the reduction rules?

Comment: Good call on the string inverse, yes you have the right idea and I will make it clear. I have a lot of test cases from when I did a number of these computations by hand in a university course and (anecdotal experience) I am pretty sure that it is possible to force the use of all the reduction rules (except maybe 4 which is really just a meta-rule for convenience when doing proofs). Additionally you have alerted me to some concerns regarding the form of the proper output: it's definitely underspecified. I'll put some work into this today.

Answer (score 2):

## **Fastest Code: checking if interval pairs overlap**

Given an unsorted input of many interval pairs (50+), write the fastest algorithm to determine if they do not overlap.

An interval pair is said to overlap if *interval x* **and** *interval y* are overlapping.

Example input 1:
interval x , interval y

```
10-25, 50-60
10-15, 25-60
```

Output:
Can be in any true false format.

```
false (They overlap)
```

reasoning:

```
a.x overlaps b.x
a.y overlaps b.y
```

Example input 2:

```
10-25, 50-60
20-30, 25-30
```

Output:

```
true (they do not overlap)
```

reasoning:

```
a.x overlaps b.x
a.y does not overlap b.y
```

Scoring:

```
[not sure...]
brute force gives a worst case n^2 runtime
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what the program is supposed to do. It's better to give three separate self-contained test cases than to mix them together with extra identifiers which won't be in the actual input. But if I understand correctly, there's nothing difficult here at all. It's just interval overlap testing (two ifs) done twice for no obvious reason.

Comment: The problem is that there will be a very large input.  I'm thinking > 50 lines.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not to score it based on time, or worst case runtime.

Comment: Instead of asking for overlap, ask for [disjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets): "Check if a family of intervals is disjoint". I also think it would be more interesting if you give intervals in [interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_notation#Excluding_the_endpoints) but I you should at least specify whether or not the endpoints are included.

Answer (score 2):

**Business Card Ray Tracer**

*I have no idea how to create a good code golf question!*

See this description of a ray tracer with source code that fits on a business card.  The author stopped when the code size was 1337 bytes.

http://fabiensanglard.net/rayTracing_back_of_business_card/index.php

Achieving identical output, optimise for minimum code size.  Execution time is not relevant.

Comment: I think what you have here is a straight ahead golf. All languages. You need only define the requirements. Do you want identical output or do you want "good output encompassing <list of features>"?

Comment: For a minimum feature list I'd suggest something like (1) it is ray tracer (2) supports point-like lights and shadow + ambient light (3) supports mirrored (implies reflection) and matte surfaces (3) all objects are sphere and overlaps are allowed. With no requirement for (a) anti-aliasing; (2) finite sized light sources; (c) atmosphere effect or (d) depth of field; or (e) tiling and gradients.  Notice however, that the example supports *at least* (b), (d) and (e).

Comment: BTW--The one you linked can get a little bit more with `#define Q return` (`R` was already taken for the `rand` wrapper) and `#define O operator`.

Comment: I suggest reading the Teapot question in the sandbox Mk IV and the comments - it's not the same question, but some of the same issues are relevant, and it might give you ideas for improvements to the spec.

Comment: Yes. Read the teapot question for guidance. Ultimately I decided that one was too big, but we did get into some pertinent details.

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score 2):

## Countdown: Federal Holidays in the United States

Inspired by this question:

[Christmas Countdown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15660/christmas-countdown)

Write a program or script that will countdown to the nearest U.S. federal holiday, at any given time, and will switch the display to an appropriate greeting during each holiday.

The following holidays must be tracked, and announced:

```
Holiday                         Date                    Greeting
==========================================================================================
New Year's Day                  Jan. 1                  Happy New Year!
Martin Luther King, Jr. Day     3rd Mon. in Jan.        Happy Martin Luther King, Jr. Day!
President's Day                 3rd Mon. in Feb.        Happy President's Day!
Memorial Day                    Last Mon. in May        Happy Memorial Day!
Independence Day                Jul. 4                  Happy Independence Day!
Labor Day                       First Mon. in Sept.     Happy Labor Day!
Columbus Day                    2nd Mon. in Oct.        Happy Columbus Day!
Veterans Day                    Nov. 11                 Happy Veterans Day!
Thanksgiving                    4th Thu. in Nov.        Happy Thanksgiving!
Christmas                       Dec. 25                 Merry Christmas!
```

The strings listed under "Holiday" and "Greeting" are all free. Shortcuts like "Merry X-mas!" or "Happy 4th of July" will count *against* you - the full and proper holiday names are free, so there's no good reason not to use them.

The following strings are also free, only when used as a label for time units or in advertising the next upcoming holiday:

```
days
hours
minutes
seconds
milliseconds
until
time
```

On any given non-holiday, the program must show a count-down timer which displays time remaining at least down to the second, and updates the display with an accurate value (according to the system clock) at least once per second. Time remaining until a holiday must be counted as the time until midnight (00:00:00) on that day.

How the days, hours, minutes, and seconds (and milliseconds, if you choose) are displayed is up to you, so long as all mandatory items are present and it is clear which numbers represent which value. Again, the strings defining units of time are free so there's no really good reason not to use them. (Though you won't be penalized for not using these strings, so long as it is still unambiguous which time units are which.) The program should also make apparent which holiday is being counted down towards.

On any given holiday, the program must cease displaying the countdown timer and instead display the appropriate greeting for that holiday from 00:00:00 until 23:59:59.

After a holiday is over, at 00:00:00 the next day, the holiday greeting must go away and be replaced with the countdown timer for the next holiday.

Answers must include:

- Name of language
- Score (length of golfed code, minus free characters)
- Golfed code
- Total length of golfed code
- Total number of free characters used
- Un-golfed code, with descriptive comments

The program must be capable of running accurately (according to the system clock) at any time, and must be able to run indefinitely. The only limitations to this should be those imposed by the host computer or the nature of the programming language.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [holidays](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holidays)

---

Are there any additions/deletions/modifications that should be made to these rules?

I'm considering changing some of the greetings, but I'm not quite sure what to.

- "Happy Martin Luther King, Jr. Day!" is just a mouthful and feels awkward, but shortening it to "Happy MLK Day" feels weird too - any other suggestions?
- I'm not quite sure "Memorial Day" should really be preceded by "Happy" - thoughts?
- Any others?

Comment: I think it would be more interesting if the strings were not free, but you still required exact match. I would like to see the compression scheme used by contestants.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is meant to be [tag:code-golf], not [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: This challenge proposal has been inactive for over a month. I would like to take ownership of the challenge and make it ready for posting. Please let me know within the next 14 days if you have any objections and would still like to finish and post this challenge yourself.

Answer (score 2):

## Efficient Testing for Armstrong Numbers

An Armstrong Number (also known by different names, including Narcissistic Number; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) for more information) is a non-negative number (for our purposes represented in base 10) that is equal to the sum of the individual digits of the number each raised to the power of the number of digits. For example:

1. Start with the three digit number 407.
2. The individual digits are 4, 0, & 7.
3. Since it is a three digit number, we raise each digit to the third power: 64 (4^3), 0 (0^3), & 343 (7^3).
4. The sum of those values is 407 (64 + 0 + 343).
5. Because the final sum is equal to the original number, it is an Armstrong Number.

By contrast:

1. Start with 47.
2. The individual digits are 4 & 7.
3. A two digit number, so raise each digit to the second power: 16 (4^2) & 49 (7^2).
4. The sum of those values is 65 (16 + 49).
5. The final sum of 65 is not the original number, so it is not an Armstrong Number.

Your mission, should you decide to accept it: Write a program in any programming language (using only standard language features and libraries) implementing the **most efficient algorithm** possible to test the numbers from 1 through 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (2<sup>64</sup>-1) inclusive for "Armstrongness", generating a list of Armstrong Numbers, and only Armstrong Numbers, as output.

While any language is acceptable, it should be obvious that interpreted scripting languages will be at a disadvantage in the efficiency department. That being said, a superior algorithm in an interpreted scripting language can beat the pants off an inefficient algorithm in hand tuned assembly language.

### Winning Criteria

The algorithm that can check all possible candidate numbers for "Armstrongness" in the least amount of time on a reference computer will be the winner. The reference computer will have the following specifications: {approximately an AMD Phenom class computer with 8 GB RAM running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit}

Comment: I don't know that this would belong in the (already very long, maybe too long) problem statement above, but other historical background. The class was for Fortran 77, and I was in a friendly competition with my TA to write the shortest version. I never could win that one, so I decided to write the most efficient version instead. Hence: I prefer efficiency puzzles to code golf (though code golf is fun too).

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an objective winning criterion. You do list "criteria I'll be using to judge this", but a) it mixes specification with winning criteria; b) it combines factors without indicating their weight.

Comment: The question also seems to be about twice as long as it needs to be. If you use the `[link text](url)` link notation you can shorten it slightly; you can also lose paragraphs by cutting the worked example and brute-force code (link to [the existing question on narcissistic numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15244/194) instead); cutting the waffling about which languages you think have advantages; and simplifying the motivation.

Comment: I think efficiency problems are not well suited to code-golf. The efficiency of an algorithm depends on too many factors. You could perhaps require the lowest number of power operations.

Comment: @ugoren, 0 is easily obtained.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, You're right. Still, trying to replace a time measurement with the number of operations of a certain type sometimes helps define the problem better.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I agree it is quite long, and will consider revisions to it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I'm open to better phrasing of the "objective winning criteria" but really, it is pretty objective already. One, no wrong answers allowed in the winner. Two, how efficient is the algorithm (based on the range of numbers tested and time taken to test them). For example, an algorithm that tests all numbers through 9 digits in 100 seconds is faster than an algorithm that takes 20 seconds to test all numbers through 8 digits (10 times larger interval in only 5 times the time). How might you suggest integration of this with the problem statement?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Glad I included the disclaimer about failing eyesight, given that I searched for narcissistic numbers and came up with nothing. I either searched the wrong portion of PCG (meta) or I made a typo when spelling narcissistic.

Comment: @ugoren: efficiency may not be suited to code golf, but my understanding was that this 'forum' was about "programming puzzles" *and* "code golf". I certainly would consider finding a more efficient algorithm to be like solving a puzzle, though maybe I'm alone in that, in which case no biggie.

Comment: Edited the problem statement (which is still admittedly quite long, still considering other edits) by removing the final PPS paragraph and replacing the existing links as suggested.

Comment: The winning criterion is still too imprecise IMO. (NB Of the judging criteria you list, the first is part of the spec, so it's an acceptability criterion rather than a winning criterion). A genuinely objective winning criterion allows me to calculate my score before I submit my answer.

Comment: It should be much shorter in order to not discourage people from approaching your challenge. Almost all the text after the definition doesn't add anything to the challenge - beside "don't print wrong numbers" which is of course relevant. I also think that a more precise criterion should be given instead.

Comment: I've posted a "radical" update to it. I suspect the new winning criteria will not be acceptable either, since it involves a "reference computer" for final timing. Very open to suggestions on how to restate it so that a crappy algorithm on fast hardware doesn't beat an efficient algorithm on slow hardware.

Comment: The possibility that processor architecture or available memory affects the results is a tricky issue with [tag:fastest-code] questions, but there isn't really a better way of comparing speed of programs than measuring on a large test case. I can at least measure how my program compares to someone else's on *my* computer, and know whether it's close or not.

Comment: One thought I had was to provide a "reference version" of the algorithm that people could use and time to compare and contrast against their algorithm. In that way they could run both on their own hardware and have a good idea how their algorithm will compare in the final analysis.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 2):

### Golf a random Human Genome fragment with non-random features

A totally random genome fragment is easy enough: just spit out the letters ATCG in random order, and you're done. So let's try something a little less random and more useful to science.

**Your program will:**

- Accept an argument from the user for **number of base pairs** (20bp-10000bp must be supported, more if you wish)
- Accept an argument from the user for **GC content**. This indicates how frequently the generated sequence should contain the G and C bases as a percentage of total sequence length.
- Include at least **one complete gene in every request of 500bp or more**, where a gene is defined as an otherwise random sequence that begins with a start codon triplet (ATG) and ends with the first stop codon triplet it encounters (TAG, TGA, or TAA). The distance between the start codon and the stop codon does *not* have to be a multiple of 3.
- **Vary gene content** (the portion of the fragment that is "gene", inclusive of the gene's start and stop codons) **linearly with respect to GC content** (when sequence >= 500bp). At the extremes, when GC content is 0%, gene content is 10%; when GC content is 100%, gene content is 60%.
- **Output a single-strand sequence** that complies with the above specs and the user's given parameters. (i.e. a single row of letters will suffice since it is trivial to deduce the complementary strand of the DNA given the sequence of one strand)
- Calculate the actual GC content %, actual number of genes, and actual gene content % in the resulting fragment, and **output a status line below the sequence** conforming to the example format below. Percentages may be rounded to one decimal place. Actual values may deviate by +/- 3% from the expected outcome based on user's input.

  GC content: 42.1% | Genes: 3 | Gene content: 32.1%

**Your program will not:**

- Use any Internet, library, or built-in gene sequence generation functions or databases. Roll your own.

**Sufficient randomness:**

- For the purposes of this challenge, any built-in random/pseudo-random number generator function, GUID generator, well-seeded cryptographic hash function, etc. is considered an acceptable source of randomness.

**What-ifs:**

- **What if another start codon occurs before the stop codon?** E.g. ATGXXXATGXXXXXXXXXXXXTAG. This is acceptable, but the "gene" length in this case is calculated from the most proximal start codon to the stop codon.
- **What if another stop codon occurs after a stop codon?** E.g. ATGXXXXXXXXXXXXXTAGXXXXXXTAG
  This is also acceptable, but likewise the "gene" length is calculated from the start to the most proximal stop.
- **What if both of these things happen?** E.g. ATGXXXATGXXXXXXXXXXXXTAGXXXTGA. Here again, the "most proximal" principle applies and the gene content is demarcated by the innermost start and the innermost stop.
- **Do "orphaned" start and stop codons that do not demarcate a gene count as gene content?** No.

This challenge is code golf, so shortest *valid* code wins.

Post example output from a 500-bp request with GC content between 35% and 65%, and have fun!

Comment: "Use hardcoded fragments for anything other than the start and stop codons." - why not? Specifying criteria for what counts as enough randomness should make these useless in any case. Speaking of which, you need to specify criteria for what counts as enough randomness.

Comment: The only partial output example given flagrantly violates the spec. If the GC content is 42.1%, the gene content should be 31.05%, not 22.0%. The definition of "gene" is also imprecise: in the sequence `AUGCCAUGCCUAGCUAA`, which is the gene?

Comment: @PeterTaylor `AUG` starts the gene, then come the `CCA`, `UGC`, `CUA` and `GCU` triplets, none of which terminate the gene. Now if there were three `C`'s instead of two, then `UAA` would be the terminating triplet and the whole sequence would form a gene. I agree the definition is imprecise, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak, (part of) the point of that example is that there are *two* `AUG` substrings.

Comment: Good points. I was hoping to avoid having too much text, but that came at the expense of less clarity than the challenge demands. Edit forthcoming.

Comment: Also, I've muddied the waters with RNA encoding and DNA encoding, (U vs T), which we can chalk up to a late night.

Comment: Revised accordingly, although I remain open to suggestions on how best to frame the standards for acceptable randomness. I want something that won't be exploited by answers making no effort at randomness, but that doesn't have the pain-in-the-butt factor of generating 10mb+ of data and running a Diehard test battery.

Comment: " This is acceptable, but the "gene" length in this case is calculated from the most proximal start codon to the stop codon. " - wait, what? [In nature, the _first_ one is the start codon, and the rest encode methionine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table). Under your scheme, methionine [(which is an essential amino-acid)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methionine) would be impossible to include into proteins. Your scheme would also be much harder to splice. Also, what happens to `AUG` substrings that are not triplet-aligned to previous `AUG` substrings?

Comment: In nature, the first `ATG` encodes the start of a protein coding region _and_ defines a reading frame (triplet boundary), the rest encode methionine and the first _triplet aligned_ stop codon encodes the end of the protein coding region (and no amino-acid).

Comment: As for the randomness, I'm not worried about the _source_ of randomness (whatever native library is available is assumed to be good enough) but rather how the source of randomness is used (can we just start the sequence with a start codon and insert an end codon at just the right spot if it doesn't occur naturally sooner, then fill in with more random codons while avoiding `ATG` subsequences? Your "sufficient randomness" places constraints on the RNG (useless) but no constraints on how it's used (or that it needs to be used at all)

Comment: My true random number sequence generator was sitting there watching silently as I typed away the sequence `ACACACACACACAC...`. It's all okay. The TRNG _was_ capable of producing something better - it just didn't really get to it.

Comment: In fact, the 3% tolerance for the CG content leaves no room for randomness  when there are only 20 base pairs. I can shuffle the pairs and turn some A<->T or C<->G, but that's it. In fact, if the CG content is set to zero, the task is impossible: we want a gene content of 2 base pairs (which is itself impossible), but the start codon contains a G, and a single G in a 2bp sequence means a 5% CG content, 2% than is the limit. Not including a gene means that we are 7% under the gene content lower limit. Similarly, it's not possible to start or stop a gene with nothing but `C`s and `G`s.

Comment: Yeah, the 20bp starting point is a bad idea. The problem with start codons is that I considered introducing the idea of promoters and decided that would make the whole thing too complex. So in the absence of promoters there has to be some way to determine which Met is the start codon vs an amino acid and the easiest simplification is to have no Mets in the gene.  Likewise, for "not triplet aligned", I'm trying to avoid having to go into explanations of frameshift mutations (even though a Frameshift% would be a cool parameter).

Comment: I am starting to think that all of these complexities should be included (this proposal stems from me noticing that most of the extant random DNA generators are pretty weak) and this should just be a popularity contest instead of a golf. Link a couple of good articles on the structure of the genetic code and let people add as many features as they wish. Making it a golf seems to be a catch-22 between too many compromises or a too-impenetrable wall of rules and conditions that will dissuade participation.

Comment: Perhaps a [tag:code-challenge] where people earn x points for each complexity implemented?

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion. I will be retooling this proposal toward that end.

Comment: Are you going to rework this or just let it die?

Comment: I'm reworking it! Have patience. I just figured I'd put up the DIM idea as well since it was less complicated.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 2):

## Unified format patcher

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Write the shortest program that will take a patch file in the [unified format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) from stdin and apply that patch. No external tools that do the process for you can be used.

#### Clarifications

- Extra documentation about the unified format can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Unified-Format)
- All file paths will be relative
- Only one file will be modified per patch
- Timestamps can be ignored
- The patch file will be valid and will apply cleanly to the file specified (it will not lie about line numbers, etc..)
- Assume all files being patched already exist, you don't need to create/delete files

#### Extra

- **-35** - Take an argument that allows you to unpatch a patch

#### Example

/test/a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

patch.txt

```
--- a/test/a.cpp
+++ b/test/a.cpp
@@ -1,7 +1,8 @@
 #include <iostream>
+#include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
-    cout << "Hello world!";
+    cout << "Goodbye world!";
     return 0;
 }
```

Run patch

```
patch.exe patch.txt
```

/test/a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Goodbye world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can the program assume that the `@@` lines contain the correct line numbers?

Comment: A good explanation of the patch file format is needed. If not too long, include it in the question. Else, provide a link.

Comment: You forgot the obvious "no external tools" disclaimer. You don't want the `patch $1` answer.

Comment: @ugoren thanks for the comments, I added some further clarifications.

Comment: Does "*The patch file will be valid (it will not lie about line numbers)*" also mean that it will apply cleanly?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes, updated question.

Comment: "The shorted program" should say "the shortest program", but other than that I think it's ready to go. Of course, no-one's actually going to do more than filter out the lines starting `-`, remove the first char from each line, and parse the line-numbers to work out how to splice the resulting text in.

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to vote to delete this.

Answer (score 2):

### DIM, the DIM Integer Machine

The DIM Integer Machine is an engine for producing integer sequences.

It has one major problem: To put it mildly, it's kind of...dim.

After producing a single number, it *immediately* forgets what sequence it was working on. The only thing it remembers is the last number it produced and the current direction of the search, either ascending or descending. (And of course, it remembers the methodology for finding numbers according to the commands it understands).

Consequently, the user is free to change their mind after each number by issuing a new command.

Suppose the DIM has just produced an integer square: 81

- User inputs `P` and submits the input.
- DIM understands that `P` is requesting the next prime number after 81
- DIM computes and returns `83`.
- DIM forgets what it was doing.
- User inputs `O`.
- DIM understands that `O` is requesting the next odious number and returns `84`.
- DIM forgets what it was doing.

**The DIM functions only for numbers between 1 and 1,000,000.** If the DIM reaches either extreme while performing a search it will reverse direction and continue searching.

(For example: If searching in ascending order for a prime when the last number was 999,999, it will encounter 1,000,000 which is not a prime, then switch to descending order and continue searching for the "next" prime by moving downward - 999,999...999,998, etc.)

The DIM remembers the last number as `1` when it is first activated for a searching session.

**This is the full list of commands that the DIM understands:**

- `P` - Next prime number
- `S` - Next square number
- `F` - Next Fibonacci number
- `O` - Next odious number
- `W` - Next wasteful number
- `U` - Next undulating number
- `K` - Next katadrome
- `R` - Reverse direction immediately; the next command will proceed in the new direction

**Because the DIM is so...dim, it absolutely DOES NOT precompute lookup tables of numbers in these sequences. It is far too forgetful for that to work.** The DIM also has no Internet connection, so it is unable to consult the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences or other such sites. It also has a sense of pride, so it does not make use of built-in Fibonacci functions or NextPrime / PrimeIndex / PrimeTest type functions.

Given the parameters it knows - a starting number, a search direction, the type of number to find - it simply computes the next number by some means other than mere data retrieval.

The DIM may accept input interactively, or from a newline-terminated text file, or from a pre-initialized array. You may not pack extraneous data other than the command sequence into the input - play fair!

**This is a code golf, so least number of bytes wins. Submit your program with output results for the following search sessions:**

1. `P O U R F O R U S O U R P R O W S`
2. `W O R K F O R P O O R F O R K S K O O P S R O O K S F O U R W O W S`
3. `P O O P O O P O O P P O O P P R O P S P R O W S P O R K S`

*It is assumed that you know what prime, square, and Fibonacci numbers are. A brief explanation of the other integer sequences follows.*

*Odious - a nonnegative number which has an odd number of 1s in its binary expansion. The first few odious numbers are 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 16, 19*

*Wasteful - a natural number that has fewer digits than the number of digits in its prime factorization (including the exponents). The first few are 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 18, 20, 22*

*Undulating - has alternating digits of the form aba, abab, ababa, etc. Assume all U numbers are non-trivial, i.e. 3 digits or more. The first few: 101, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212*

*Katadrome - A number whose hexadecimal digits are in strict descending order. The first few are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 32, 33, 48, 49*

Comment: When I post the question, I'll also include external links to MathWorld or OEIS for those who need more detail on the less familiar sequences, but the explanations above should be sufficient for most, I think.

Comment: Your definition of "undulating" isn't the one I'm familiar with, which just requires that the digits alternately increase and decrease. Also, it would be better to include expected answers for the test cases, so that submitters can use them as test cases rather than them serving just for you to say "No, this is buggy".

Comment: Yes, that's my plan, I just haven't finished double checking my results for the test cases yet. OEIS and Mathworld have the strict 2-digit definition of undulating, but I'll make sure to make the definition here more prominent so it is clear which interpretation is meant.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 2):

### Amino Acids Matcher

In genetics, a codon is a set of three nucleotides, the most basic form of nucleic acids. A codon "codes" (no pun intended, that's the actual term used) for a specific amino acid. Given a string of DNA, it is converted into RNA form by taking the opposite complementary pair.

```
DNA    RNA
A      U (T changes to U)
T      A
C      G
G      C
```

You will be given a String of unknown length that contains multiple codons. You must convert them to RNA form and print out the amino acid for each. See here for a chart: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_codon_table#RNA_codon_table

---

### Sample Input

`TACTCGGATACT`

Is split into

`TAC`, `TCG`, `GAT`, `ACT`

We now change each letter to its reciprocal

`AUG`, `AGC`, `CUA`, `UGA`

And print out the amino acids

`Methionine, Serine, Leucine, Stop`

---

This would probably be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**I know that this is most likely not sufficiently explained and might be too complicated. Additional, tell me if there is any incorrect information above.**

Comment: So basically this is a challenge to compress a lookup table. You should probably specify that the string will be a multiple of three characters (or specify what to do otherwise); and it would seem sensible to inline the lookup table so that a) the question doesn't rely on the external page remaining intact; b) you save everyone who wants to answer the question the hassle of calculating it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update accordingly later today.

Answer (score 2):

### Collatz ...something

The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) states that every natural number `n` leads to the number `1` if the recursive function `f(n)` is applied to it defined as

```
f(n)=n/2    if n is even
    =3n+1   if n is odd
```

Let "a<sub>i</sub>" be the value of `f` applied to `n` recursively `i` times so that a<sub>0</sub> = n , a<sub>1</sub> = f(n) , a<sub>2</sub> = f(f(n)) ... a<sub>i</sub> = f(a<sub>i-1</sub>)

Let `A` be the set {a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., 1}

Thus, for n=10, we get the sequence

a<sub>0</sub> = 10 --> a<sub>1</sub> = 5 --> a<sub>2</sub> = 16 --> a<sub>3</sub> = 8 --> a<sub>4</sub> = 4 --> a<sub>5</sub> = 2 --> a<sub>6</sub> = 1

and the set `A` as `A = {10,5,16,8,4,2,1}`

Your task is to write a function/program that will accept a set of naturals say `I`. You must output a set of numbers say `C` such that `I` is a subset of the union of the sets `A` for all numbers in `C`.

#### Rules

- Network access is forbidden
- Any of the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are forbidden
- Your program must end in less than 200 seconds. You may assume that all the input terms are less than `2^(45)`; however note that the individual terms of the collatz sequence can go higher.

#### Input

- List/array of naturals in `I` as an argument to a function
- `,` or `space` or `\n` separated naturals in `I` on `STDIN`

#### Output

- `return` a list/array/set of all naturals in `C`
- `print` all the naturals in `C` separated by `\n`

#### Scoring

Your score is calculated as

```
( ( (10)^(number of elements in C) ) * (sum of all elements in C) ) + ceil( 100*log(total number of bytes of your code) )
```

<sup>log() is the natural logarithm</sup>

Lowest score wins.

#### Examples

Input:

```
I = { 16 , 32 , 40 }
```

Possible outputs along with the score

```
C=                   Score

{ 16 , 32 , 40 }     ((10)^(3))*(16 + 32 + 40) = 8000   + constant
{ 32 , 40 }          ((10)^(2))*(32 + 40)      = 7200   + constant
{ 32 , 13 }          ((10)^(2))*(32 + 13)      = 4500   + constant --> most optimal         
{ 1024 , 320 }       ((10)^(2))*(1024 + 320)   = 134400 + constant
... Infinitely many higher numbers
```

where `constant` is `ceil(100*log(code length))`

In this case, the answer `{ 32 , 13 }` is the most optimal.

---

Note: This is NOT code-golf even though the length of your program is considered. Please also provide a readable version.

I'm being flexible with the I/O so that the more verbose languages might get some benefit. You can write a complete program or a function or a lambda function. It is not required that your function(if you choose to write one) returns. Using a function for input while printing the output is fine if that makes the code shorter.

---

This will be tagged as [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

---

### Sandbox feedback

- Can anyone suggest a better title?

### TODO

- Scoring needs specific test cases. Perhaps the final score could be the average of all scores of the test cases.
- Needs a proper title.

Comment: The timing constraint is not reasonable unless you also provide constraints on the number and size of the inputs. For any input for which the constraint is reasonable at all, I think that the first point of the spec is unnecessary: if a counterexample exists, it's right at the edge of what fits in a 64-bit number. The second point of the spec is currently quite difficult to understand.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is it OK now?

Comment: Looking around a bit at the standard terminology, I think that it might be best introduced with something like "Each positive integer `n` generates a *Collatz sequence* by repetition of the map `f(n) = n % 2 == 0 ? n/2 : 3*n+1`. Define the *orbit* of `n` as the set containing the integers in its Collatz sequence, and the orbit of a set `{n_i}` as the union of the individual elements' orbits. Your task is to find an optimal set under the constraint that its orbit contain a specified subset." That then leads into the example.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's justifiable to claim that for your example `{I2, C5, C10}` is "*(not the most ideal)*". Whether or not it is depends on which arrows are `/2` and which are `*3+1`, which isn't shown in the example. It's also occurred to me, which I missed earlier, that your scoring system requires a bit more of a test suite: at present, you have no way of distinguishing between answers which get the optimal solution to one test case. And I suggest a title, based on my previous comment: "Optimal Collatz orbits".

Comment: I suggest you to add a link describing what is a *collatz sequence*. As a non-mathematician, I find it hard to understand. There is extra whitespaces after `\` in your first code block.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Edited a lot. Are you sure it is called an `orbit`? I couldn't find that term anywhere.

Comment: It occurs 4 times in the Wikipedia page on the Collatz conjecture, and Google gives over 6 million hits for `collatz orbit`.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 2):

## Find words in word square solver

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

On social media I often see images with letters and in them are some positive words for people to find. I challenge you to write a program that finds all words in the puzzle that matches a input dictionary. An example of such puzzle is this one:

[image: A letter square]

An ASCII representation I made of this:

```
XCUALOVEYKBWSNG
DUAWKCBEAUTYRJV
YOUTHFSMGNEZLPR
MHJREYWDKZLUSTJ
FSUCCESSDHEALTH
ENMQXPTIMELMSAQ
VEXPERIENCEGHBW
GHUMOURLOYMONEY
SYZPOPULARITYNA
AMKCFUNBXHUZYIX
CWIHYSHAPPINESS
HONESTYCFRIENDS
KPYJAETWPOWERQC
BTYACFREEDOMJMO
RIWINTELLIGENCE
```

Now I imagine we can find words horizontally, vertical and diagonal and all of the mentioned in reverse. The program must be able to take a square and a dictionary [like this one](http://www.curlewcommunications.co.uk/wordlist.html) and print all the matching words.

As a test case I give custom dictionary:

```
bar
bid
dir
dog
fad
fed
foo
god
man
mod
set
sun
```

And a test square:

```
OGFIR
DOMAN
ODBID
OPGES
OGFIR
```

Your code should be able to print all but the two last words in the dictionary. For diversity you should specify how the cube and the dictionary is bo be entered.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

Comment: What should be output? Only the matched words? Their positions? And directions?

Comment: @JanDvorak Just print the words found. Do you think coordinates and direction can be given a bonus?

Comment: Cube? I'm only seeing two dimensions. On a more general note, perhaps for questions of this sort it would be OK to assume the availability of a standard dictionary file like `/usr/share/dict`, and discount the characters used to access this file? What do people think?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage OMG You're right. I meant square of course :-) I think people can choose. eg. The question is open for diversity like `cat square.txt dic.txt | solver` now, but I'm open for change that does not discriminate.

Comment: How does the program know where the wordsearch ends and the dictionary starts?

Comment: @PeterTaylor By mistake I made the test a rectagle, but I fixed that. The length of the first line would be the number of lines in the square. Anyway how the input is done I thought should be up to the solver so that they can choose to open files, read stdin or maybe more disturebing ways to get input in...

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: @programmer5000 It only got two upvotes so I let it be. Feel free to post it if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

## Filter out repetitive lines

Google Suggest doesn't show any results if a string contains more than 4 repetitions of a substring. More specifically, if a substring is repeated 4 times in a row, followed by the first character of that substring (i.e. `abcabcabcabca` or `x x x x x`), nothing is suggested. This rule changes slightly if the substring is all the same digit - a digit may be repeated 5 times in a row, but no more. This is probably to allow searching for ZIP codes like `22222`. (This doesn't extend to strings like `1010101010`, though.)

Let's simulate this behavior! **Write a program that takes lines on standard input and echoes those lines back on standard output, unless the line fits the criteria for repetitiveness, in which case it's silently discarded.**

Sample input:

```
a simple query
nananananananana
ffffgggghhhh
48719999936
abc abc abc abc asdf
xyzzzzzyx
122333444455555666666
repetitiverepetitiverepetitiverepetitive
erepetitiverepetitiverepetitiverepetitive
101010101
55555 zzzzz
```

Output:

```
a simple query
ffffgggghhhh
48719999936
repetitiverepetitiverepetitiverepetitive
```

*(Google's behavior is actually quite a bit more complicated than this; there are a few exceptions to all of these rules, but let's just ignore those for this challenge.)*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings)

---

There was a similar challenge posted awhile ago ([Recognizing Repetition in strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/recognizing-repetition-in-strings)), but it was closed due to vagueness. I think the criteria proposed above are more than thorough enough.

Comment: The current exceptions make it complicated enough to track what you're looking for: basically you're asking for `grep -v ((.).+)\2{3}\1|([^0-9])\3{4}`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would like to try to solve it without regex, though.

Comment: I had thought about regex, but I didn't think it would be that simple. Would adding more restrictions or banning regex help?

Comment: @Fraxtil, my opinion is that as a general rule if you need to ban the obvious way of doing something then you might as well just abandon the question. (With the exception, obviously, of banning libraries which are specifically designed to solve the same problem. Regex being a general tool rather than something designed for this specific problem don't fall into that exception).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, that's a good point. Maybe I'll revisit the idea later if I can find a way to make it more interesting.

Comment: I did make a [decent question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21841/shortest-program-to-split-a-string-at-non-digits-without-regexps) out of doing a basic regex problem without the use of regex (I should have, in hind sight, banned basic pattern matching as well as regexes...Bash shouldn't almost beat APL in sheer character count in a code golf).

Comment: @impinball "Bash shouldn't almost beat APL in sheer character count in a code golf" -- why?

Comment: Or at least in that context (`tr` is a pattern matching replace algorithm with regex like functionality). I would be a little more likely to accept Bash's builtin pattern matching expansion than `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

## Am I a Matroid?

### Input:

A list `I` that is a subset of the powerset of `E={1,2,...,n}` which represents the independent sets of elements of the purported matroid `M=(E,I)`. Note that the cardinality of the ground set may be for the purposes of this question ignored. Any elements of `E` that appear in none of the elements of `I` cannot contribute (i.e. if `M=(E,I)` is a matroid then `M=(E union K,I)` is a matroid for any set `K`.

Input may be in whatever list format you desire, be it as simple as no separators but spaces (using `0` for the empty set): `0 1 2 3 12 13` or as complicated as whatever list literals are in your favorite language (such as python's: `[[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3]]`).

### Output:

A variation on `1/0`, `true/false`, `yes/no` answering the question: is `M` a matroid?

### Definition:

`M=(E,I)` is a matroid if:

1. `I` is not the empty set
2. If `J` is in `I` and `K` is a subset of `J`, then `K` is in `I`
3. If `J,K` are in `I` and `|K|<|J|` then there exists an element `x` that is in the set difference `J-K` such that `K union {x}` is in `I`.

There are equivalent formulations of condition 1 and 3, also there are conditions on the bases (maximal elements of `I` w.r.t. cardinality) that are equivalent to these. If people want I can post those too or leave them as optional research.

### Examples:

`I={{},{1},{2},{1,2}}` is a matroid.

`I={}` is not a matroid because it is empty (by axiom 1).

`I={{},{1},{1,3}}` is not a matroid because if it has `{1,3}` independent then it must have `{3}` independent (by axiom 2).

`I={{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2}}` is not a matroid because if it has `{1,2}` and `{3}` independent then it must have either `{1,3}` or `{2,3}` independent (by axiom 3).

`I={{}}` is always a matroid, as is `I=powerset([1,2,...,n])` for any `n>0` as they both trivially satisfy the axioms.

### Specs:

Submission is either a program taking input from standard input or command line argument or a function that takes `I` as input (as a string) and returns the specified binary answer. No upperbound on the size of input should be hardcoded.

I would intend for this to be a code-golf challenge.

Comment: Rather than provide alternative definitions, just link the first mention of the word *matroid* to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 2):

### md5sum Creator

This is my first code golf challenge; critiquing welcome.

Your task is to create a new md5sum function. You need to output to STDOUT the `input`, a space **or** a tab character, the md5sum, then a new line. The spec for an md5sum can be found [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt), thanks to the IETF. For example:

```
1 c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
2 c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
... 
//hashes generated on http://www.md5.cz/
```

- You may use existing libraries *so long as you are not directly calling an md5sum function from within that library*.
- Output is not case sensitive (`A` is the same as `a` when it comes to an md5sum).
- Your program/function will take in a string, and output the md5sum as a string
- No downloading data from the Internet.
- Code Golf, so the shortest answer wins!

Comment: what should the output file be called? isn't it easier to use STDOUT? and should the character separating the number and its md5 be a tab or a space or the correct number of spaces?

Comment: Is the output case-sensitive?

Comment: @professorfish Edited. Thanks for the input.

Comment: MD5 takes a sequence of octets, so how should I pack my integers? Should I pack 4 bytes in network byte order? Or little-endian? Or format each integer in ASCII? Or UTF-16?

Comment: In that case, do you need to update your sample output? All online md5 generators I've used treat input as ASCII.

Comment: Done @PeterTaylor. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problems with this now.

Comment: I'd prefer if you included the relevant parts of the MD5 spec in the answer. I don't feel like reading an entire RFC to compete in the challenge, and challenges should generally be self-contained anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## Type me out.

Your task (related to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32654/9534)) is to translate any text (in a file, or simply input) into the input of a telephone keypad.

[image]

and provide a keypress score.

As the keypad has a limited set of keys you have to 'encode' your non-alphanumerics with their ASCii hexadecimal encoding; e.g. to type ~ you press the hash key once, the 7 key (once to get a seven) and then 3 three times to cycle through the digits 3, 'd', and finally 'e'. This gives the code #7e which corresponds to ~. Spaces and capitals have to be accessed via hex code (so MY_CONST (`#4d #59 #53def #43 #4f #4e #53 #54` - 27 presses) costs you less than my_const (`6m 9wxy #53def 2bc 6mno 6mn 7pqrs 8t` - 29), but more than myconst  (`6m 9wxy 2bc 6mno 6mn 7pqrs 8t` - 23)).

> For instance If your code had `print()` that would cost 15 for the print
>   (7p 7pqr 4ghi 6mn 8t) plus 6 for the () (#28 #29)

To be clear with just the input  `print()` the output is:

```
7p 7pqr 4ghi 6mn 8t #28 #29
21
```

(Note however the hex codes for `c f i r s v y z` are shorter (correspondingly `#63 #66 #69 #72 #73 #76 #79 #7a`) than long hand key presses. It's perfectly allowed to score `print()` as 19:

```
7p #72 #69 6mn 8t #28 #29
19
```

)

This is Code Golf, so feed your code into the finished program - shortest answer wins.

Comment: @m.buettner typically when typing on a phone keypad you have to press the number first, and each subsequent press is a letter and then it cycles round. Spaces have to be hex values, capitals require hex codes as well. Scoring is as you state.

Comment: @m.buettner I added them as soon as I had finished replying to your comment. Is it clear enough now. And yes you can use those short cuts instead of typing them long. I'll add that in a second.

Comment: Better! :) ... I think `myconst` should be 24 though. And your output for that is somewhat different from your example output later one. Where you show the counting you only write the resulting letter whereas in the actual example output you show the sequence. Which also raises the question whether letters in hex codes should be expanded in the actual output (which would be necessary for correct counting).

Comment: @m.buettner I'm not very good at this challenge, that's why I need people to so it for me! I'll update the score now, and clarify the output as well.

Comment: @m.buettner How is it now? Ready?

Comment: I think so, but you should wait for two other people to tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

### Reindent Java/C/C++/etc. code

Write a program that adds or removes whitespace to format code nicely. Rules for what the code should look like when you're done:

- No line should contain more than one of `{` and `}`.
- A `{` should always be the last thing on a line.
- A `}` should always be the *only* thing on a line (besides whitespace that comes before it).
- The amount of whitespace in front of each line should be a fixed multiple of the current nesting count. (You can use any amount of indentation you want, as long as it doesn't change.)
- No whitespace should be inserted or removed that doesn't contribute to satisfying one of these rules.

The nesting count for the first line is 0. The nesting count of any other line is the nesting count of the previous line, plus one if the previous line contains a `{`, minus one if the current line contains a `}`.

`{` and `}` inside string literals and comments don't count in the above rules. A string literal is text enclosed in single or double quotes, where single or double quotes with a backslash before them aren't interpreted as the end of the string literal. A comment is text enclosed in `/*` and `*/`, or text going from `//` to the end of the line. `/*` `*/` comments can be nested.

For example, it should reformat this:

```
    main() {printf("Hello!"); // I don't care about the world...
        }
```

into this:

```
main() {
    printf("Hello!"); // I don't care about the world...
}
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Strictly interpreted, the current rules don't allow any legal output for input `"{}"`. You probably need to define rules for string literals and comments. I also note that you don't require the indentation to be consistent (different lines can use different multiples of the nesting count), and that inputs with badly indented lines which aren't adjacent to `{` or `}` can't be fixed by inserting or removing whitespace adjacent to `{` or `}`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed those problems. (I think).

Comment: Fixed some of them. You still need to add exceptions for `{` or `}` inside a string literal or comment, including definitions for what constitutes a string literal or comment (since it varies between languages).

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh, now I understand what you meant.

Comment: @tbodt I'd like to take over this challenge if you don't plan on posting it

Comment: @musicman523 nah I think i'll post it

Comment: imo the first code snippet is better than the latter

Answer (score 2):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

## Find the mines!

Tags: [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

You are a mine remover. Your job is to find all mines on a field, without a mine explodes. So, you write an application that can find the mines carefully.

### The input

The input can either be provided through command line arguments or through STDIN (tell what you use in your submission). The input items are separated by commas.

The input looks like this:

```
<current step (zero-based)>,<mine count>,<field width>,<field height>,<field data>
```

The field data is like a Minesweeper field. Rows in the field data are separated by semicolons, columns are separated by nothing, as each column is just one character. Here are the characters you can get:

- `X` This means that you don't yet know what's there, the real data is still hidden. At the start, you get a field full of `X`s.
- `/` This means that there is nothing on that location.
- `<number>` Specifies the count of mines around the location of the number.
- `F` This is marked by a flag by you.
- `?` This got a question mark from you. There might be a mine on it, but you are not sure. This is just used as a reminder for you, it doesn't mean something specific to the controller.

Example input:

```
2,1,3,3,XX1;X1X;XXX
```

That input means that it's currently your third step, there is one mine, the field is 3x3, and the field looks like:

```
X X 1
X 1 X
X X X
```

### The output

The output consists of 4 parts: the `X` of which you want to see the data (like a click in Minesweeper), the location on which you want to put a flag mark, the location on which you want to put a question mark and a sign, used to let the controller know whether you are finished or not (`0` for not finished, `1` for finished). Locations are written as `X;Y`, zero-based. If there is something you don't want to do, output `-1`. You can also remove flags/question marks using the same way.

Example output:

```
4;3,-1,3;3
```

### Specifications

- If your first output data is the location of a mine, you hit the mine and you die, but you'll still get a score.
- If you select a `X` which hides an empty location (`/`), all adjacent empty fields (and their borders, which are numbers) will be revealed.
- For every step, your program is executed again with the updated arguments.
- When looking for mines, you are allowed to have more flags than the amount of mines. Only if you finish, the amount of flags must not be more than the amount of mines. If the amount of flags is greater than the amount of mines, your submission is disqualified (for every test!) and excluded from the scoreboard.

### Testing

When I test your submission, I'll run 100 tests on every submission, with randomly generated fields, which I created using a program that I'll write after I got some feedback. Every submission gets the same test fields, so it's fair. Test fields look like this:

- 10 tests with a 10x10 field and 10 mines.
- 10 tests with a 10x10 field and 12 mines.
- 10 tests with a 12x12 field and 14 mines.
- 10 tests with a 15x10 field and 16 mines.
- 10 tests with a 15x15 field and 35 mines.
- 10 tests with a 20x20 field and 40 mines.
- 10 tests with a 25x25 field and 50 mines.
- 10 tests with a 25x25 field and 60 mines.
- 10 tests with a 50x50 field and 100 mines.
- 10 tests with a 50x50 field and 125 mines.

### Scoring

You get 10 points for every mine you find, you lose 5 points if you think there is a mine somewhere when there is none and you lose 2 points for every mine you missed. The scoring is always the same, it doesn't matter whether you finish or die. The highest score wins.

In case of a tie, the count of steps is a tie breaker.

### Controller

I'll start working on this after I got some feedback.

Comment: You say "like Minesweeper" a couple of times, but on a cursory read I didn't see anything which differentiates it from Minesweeper. Why is this not a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24118/194 ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor You are right, only the winning criterion is different. As there is many discussion going on about these dupes with only a different winning criterion, I'll wait for some more opinions about whether it is different enough or not.

Comment: Maybe you could distinguish it by more than just the winning criterion. How about something crazy like a 3d grid of cubes where you can only access cubes that can be reached from the outside, so you slowly clear it from the outside in.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I'm not sure what you mean by "where you can only access cubes that can be reached from the outside".

Comment: That bit isn't essential - a 3d grid would work without that restriction. What I mean is restricting the cubes that can be uncovered or marked to just those on the outside of the big cube at first. Imagine it like breaking blocks to get through to blocks behind them.

Comment: The equivalent in the 2d minefield would be treating the 2d playing area as an actual field which you have to walk across, so you can't walk to a square you want to test without testing the squares on a path to it first.

Comment: 3d was just my 1st idea - but you could make it different in other ways. You could stick with the integer grid of squares to uncover, but let the mines beneath the grid take on floating point positions. The number in an uncovered square would be floating point because each of the eight squares adjacent to it may contain only part of a mine (which would explode if any of the squares it is overlapping were uncovered). If mines are squares the same size as the grid squares, then it may take 1, 2 or 4 flagged squares per mine, and each flagged square may contain overlap with 1, 2 or 4 mines.

Comment: A simpler change would be to keep everything integer but let the mines be 2x2 squares.

Comment: @githubphagocyte Thanks for your comments! What about just changing it into a 3d grid, but keep the 'normal' rules? Doing what you said about only accessing blocks if you broke the block that hides it looks complicated to implement. Unfortunately, there will still be one problem left: [if everyone would post an optimal solution, then the scoreboard will boil down to luck](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16764050#16764050).

Comment: Yes I think with the normal rules there will be a clear optimal solution. I guess even working in from the outside there would still be only one objectively best move at each step.

Comment: If you want to avoid the possibility of an optimal solution, there are 2 possibilities. 1.Make it a king of the hill and somehow have bots competing against each other in the same minefield. That way an optimal solution against one bot will be sub-optimal against another. 2.Make a change to the game that makes the search space too large for an optimal solution to be found. Then answers will consist of interesting heuristics and there will be the possibility of continually finding better solutions over a long period of time.

Comment: @githubphagocyte Your KotH suggestion is a good idea, thanks! I'll think of a good way to do this.

Comment: I guess just taking turns would work. You'd just need to decide the winning criteria: survivor when the opponent hits a mine / player who identifies the most mine / player who uncovers the most safe squares / ...

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Comment: Hey @programmer5000, feel free to adopt it.

Answer (score 2):

## The Painter's Predicament

This would be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question. This is my first question, so any guidance is appreciated.

A painter is commissioned to paint the outer wall of a house shaped as a regular `n`-gon, with walls `0` through `n-1`. Each one of these walls must be painted one of 26 colors, represented by the letters `A` through `Z`.

Thanks to the unstoppable forward march of technology, the painter has acquired a machine that can paint entire walls at once. The machine can move around the house, and can only have one color active at a time. This machine has 5 buttons. The buttons behave as follows:

```
Button #1 moves the entire machine to the wall to its left. 
Button #2 moves the entire machine to the wall to its right. 
Button #3 advances the current color forwards, so that A->B, B->C, and so on, until Z->A.
Button #4 is identical to Button #3, but instead moves the color backwards.
Button #5 paints the wall in front of it with the current color.
```

When producing an estimate for a job, the painter would like to know how many buttons he'll have to press. Your task is to find that number for a given job.

---

#### Input

Input is given to you as a series of characters representing the desired coloring of the house.

For most, that will probably be a string, but you may accept them in whatever form is convenient for your language. If your language prefers them as a character array, from stdin, abandoned on the stack, or written straight into /dev/null, you may assume that as the input format.

Examples: `ABCDEF`, `ZZZZZZ`, and `AAAAAC`.

You may also choose to have the input be in the form of `[n] [job]`, if that is more convenient for you desired input format.

Examples: `3 ABC`, `10 QRSTUVFGHJ`

You may not accept `n` as a separate piece of data. If you choose to have it be provided, it must be included in the input character series as specified.

---

#### Output

You must output the minimum number of button presses required to paint the entire house. This, again, may be done in whatever paradigm your language employs. Printing or returning the number are both definitely acceptable; the number must simply be made available to whomever invokes the code.

---

#### Additional Details

The house starts with all of its walls painted color `A`. If a job specifies that a wall must be painted `A`, it does not need to be repainted.

The machine starts at wall `0`, with current color `A`.

`n` is at least `3`.

Comment: does the machine have to start with its color set to A? does it have to start off pointed at wall 0?

Comment: Good catches, yes, and yes. I'll edit it in.

Comment: If a 3 is passed in, is the house a triangular prism?

Comment: Yep. I suppose I should lower bound `n`, since it doesn't make much physical sense to have `n` < 2.

Comment: Some test cases would be good.

Comment: This looks to be a Travelling Salesman problem on the rectangle grid graph (with one dimension looped around). It's open whether it's NP hard (http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P54.html), which means no polynomial-time algorithm is know. This mean optimal solutions probably take very long to find. Is there a time limit?

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by lifecompetes.com

## Multiplayer Game of Life (*GOL*)

There are `n` players that play the Game of Life (standard rules) on an `50 x 50` grid. (Size, border conditions? Toroidal, Absorbing, Mirroring?)

#### Before first GOL-Step

When the game starts, each player has 12 cells that he can place anywhere he want as long as they do not overlap. Before the first GOL-step occures every player has to place 6 cells. If two players place their cell on the same spot no cell wil be placed an thei cells will remain in each players bank.

#### During game

In each GOL-Step, each player can place as many new cell on the grid as he has in his bank. If two or more players want to place a cell on the same spot, no cell will be placed there (the cells will remain in each players bank). Every six GOL-steps all the players who have less that 12 cells in their bank will get a new cell in their bank.

#### Goal

The goal is achieving the maximum number of cells on the grid during 1000 GOL-steps.

#### How to participate

Each participant has to write a javascript function of the following form (multiple return statements allowed.)

```
function my_bots_name(field, bank, golstep){
  /* your code */
  return p;
}
```

Where `p` is a 2d array of points `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],...]` that the player wants to set. `field` contains a 2d array of the GOL grid, `bank` indicates the number of cells in the player's bank, and `golstep` is the index of the current GOL step (`golstep == 0` before the first GOL-step occurs).
The function may not the global variables and cannot access Math.random() or Date(). In `field` the empty cells will be set to 0, the own cells will be set to 2 and the other player's cells will be set to 1. (You will not be able to distinguish between various other players.)

The winner will be determined with a game that contains all valid submissions after one week after the first submission.

## TODO

The exact environment will be provided so everyone can test the own function before the official runs.

- What size of the grid is appropriate? (dependent on number of players?)
- How many steps should be computed?
- What border conditions should be chosen?
- Is the restriction of Math.random() and Date() apropriate? (The idea was that the games will be the same no matter of who/when they will be run. (Deterministic) )

Comment: [relevant](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi-retired/1332#1332). [also relevant](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16164270#16164270).

Comment: It looks like it was abandoned, since the user has not been here for more than a month. I was not able to read everything yet - is there something important that should be considered or is it a challenge that shouln't even be started?

Comment: I just thought you might want to have a look to get some inspiration from a previous spec.

Comment: Ok thank you, I wil read them later.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard rules"? The standard rules for Life have binary cells, and this doesn't.

Comment: Well each cell of the grid can have two states: occupied by a live cell or not. For executing a GOL-Step it does not matter which cell is of which player, they are all treated the same. (As it is in lifecompetes.com)

Comment: What happens to an empty cell that has 3 neighbours of different players? Are new cells only born if they have 3 neighbours of the same player?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I did never think about this special case but I just checked livecompetes and they handle this as follows: A new cell is born if two or three of the neighbours are from the same player. If there are three different players invovled the space remains empty.

Comment: why n players instead of 2 players?

Comment: Can you provide some thoughts why only two players would make a better game? If you could start it with n players at once you can let all submissions compete against each other as you do in the original lifecompetes.com

Comment: @programmer5000 Yes, feel free to adopt! Just make sure work out the details in the sandbox before posting. If you want me to help in one way or another, just ping me!

Comment: Can you add support for other languages?

Comment: @programmer5000 I thought *you* wanted to adopt it?!?

Comment: Please next time say that you want to *list* it for adoption rather than adopting it yourself!

Answer (score 2):

### Old fashioned intelligence gathering

As we've heard in the news, some intelligence agencies have decided to go back to typewriters due to the security hazards of the Internet.  You are a spy.  In spite of this change in policy to make messages more secure, one of your contacts scores an intelligence treasure trove: rolls of spent typewriter tape from your enemy.

The only problem?  Whomever your enemy spy agency hired was a *really* bad typist.  In fact, they tended to hit as many wrong keys as they did write.  So when you read out the first bit of tape, you see

> DQSIRINKSFIJATOAPQFFOUSJAR

Yikes.  That's some attrocious typing.  Seriously, there's training tools for that.  Anyways, you're in luck.  You *also* scored the correction tape:

> QSIFIJOAPQFSJA

After racking your brain for hours, you realize someone just wanted some booze:

```
DQSIRINKSFIJATOAPQFFOUSJAR  (ink tape)
-QSI-----FIJ--OAPQF---SJA-  (correction tape)
D---RINKS---AT-----FOU---R  
DRINKS AT FOUR              (message)
```

There's a lot of tape though, and you know there's some good intelligence information here, so you write an program to determine the original messages after filtering out the massive amounts of typos.

### Rules

Input

- a return-delimited dictionary file
- ink tape letters (all caps)
- correction tape letters (all caps)

Output

- all possible original messages ordered from fewest to most words in message; there shall be no specified ordered for messages with the same number of words.  If the intended message were `MY GRANDMOTHER HAS A LIFELONG PASSPORT`, the output should generate the following (going from 6 words to 9 words):

  - `MY GRANDMOTHER HAS A LIFELONG PASSPORT`
    `MY GRAND MOTHER HAS A LIFELONG PASSPORT`
    `MY GRANDMOTHER HAS A LIFE LONG PASSPORT`
    `MY GRANDMOTHER HAS A LIFELONG PASS PORT`
    `MY GRAND MOTHER HAS A LIFE LONG PASSPORT`
    `MY GRAND MOTHER HAS A LIFELONG PASS PORT`
    `MY GRANDMOTHER HAS A LIFE LONG PASS PORT`
    `MY GRAND MOTHER HAS A LIFE LONG PASS PORT`

Other notes

- all words in the original message will be spelled correctly (the typist was terrible, but they worked hard to eventually craft a correct sentence).
- you *may* precapitalize your dictionary
- all messages are alpha only (no numbers or punctuation)

Scoring:

- Code golf, shortest code wins.

Additional sample tapes your assistant decoded to use to test your algorithm:

```
NUAFCLEAIEOJRWARWESHEADAJIOWGUNDSUIVHERCSNZXAPITASAOIDLBUIJOVEMOLDINGIAS (ink tape)
AFIEOJWESAJIOWGSUIVHSNZXSAOIDJOVEMOIAS (correction tape)
NUCLEAR WARHEAD UNDER CAPITAL BUILDING  (decoded messages)
NUCLEAR WAR HEAD UNDER CAPITAL BUILDING 

ASSLEDELPERIWECERSPDLLSACFSPTIVVOXATEIQPTREOIOSJFNMORROAIOW (ink tape)
ASDLIWERSPDFSPVOXIQPREOISJFNOAI (correction tape)
SLEEPER CELLS ACTIVATE TOMORROW (decoded messages)
SLEEPER CELLS ACTIVATE TO MORROW

ASOIIJHAWQRATEMSDQPOYJKWEOABS (ink tape)
ASOIJWQRASDQPOKWEAS (correction tape)
I HATE MY JOB (decoded message)
```

Comment: So I get a -25 bonus just for adding "HELOVESNAPTIMESATTWOTHIRTY" to my post? It can be parsed as English words at least two ways, with one making sense. You may want to get rid of that bonus; ambiguously segmented words can be easily Googled.

Comment: Also, any message that included any compound word would automatically qualify. This includes WAR|HEAD from your example.

Comment: Good point. This is what I get when running on less sleep than I need haha. Was thinking of more interesting crossword boundary combinations, but obviously there was an easier solution I didn't think about. I'll take it off

Comment: `MOT HER` and `MOTH ER` are also in good dictionaries, as are `PAS SPORT`. And if the dictionary is for spelling correction rather than for word games, it might allow `LI FELON GPAS SPORT`. For the purposes of giving test cases it would be better to specify a dictionary file.

Comment: @PeterTaylor true, although the idea is they'd be pushed farther down the list (fewer words being more likely, though not guaranteed, the intended message).  Do you have a dictionary you know of that would be well-suited that I could link to?  (come to think of it, having made a spell checker before for a highly inflected language, this is definitey something that would be truly evil for less analytical languages)

Comment: I would suggest picking one from http://wordlist.aspell.net/12dicts-readme/ , although earlier questions have used others ([1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/693/194), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5136/194)).

Answer (score 2):

## The Tetris Tournament

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

[We've implemented Tetris before.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11175/8478) But we haven't played it yet. So you're to write a bot which plays Tetris in real time!

### The Rules

We're playing standard Tetris. That is, there will be one falling [one-sided tetromino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino), which you can move and rotate until it hits the bottom. Complete lines of blocks get cleared, which causes all lines above to shift down accordingly. You will always be aware of the next tetromino. The goal is to clear as many lines as possible while the game gets faster.

Here are the specifics of rules which differ among various Tetris implementations:

The board will be 10 blocks wide and 22 blocks tall. The top two rows are "off-screen": tetrominoes will not spawn in the top two rows, but may be rotated into these.

The [right-handed Nintendo Rotation System](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Nintendo_Rotation_System) will be used (which is equivalent to the original rotation system). That is, each piece is basically in a square bounding box and cycles through 1 to 4 fixed patterns within that bounding box [as given by this chart](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Nintendo_Rotation_System?file=NESTetris-pieces.png). Each tetromino will spawn in the first of its orientations such that its top-most blocks are in the top on-screen row, and the piece is centred horizontally (rounded to the left).

There is no [wall kick](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_kick) or [floor kick](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Floor_kick). If a rotation would lead to overlapping or out-of-bounds blocks, it will be ignored.

There is a [lock delay](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Lock_delay) equal to current step duration. That is, tetrominoes lock into place when the controller tries to move them down but hits another block or the floor.

The sequence of tetrominoes is determined by the [Random Generator](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Generator). That is, whenever the queue for pieces is empty, a random permutation of all 7 tetrominoes will be enqueued. I will add one exception to this: when the game starts, a random number of tetrominoes will be discarded from the first permutation, such that it's not immediately obvious where one ends and the next starts.

"Pressing" *down* does a [soft drop](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Drop). In particular, it will move the tetromino down one row without resetting the timer for the next drop due to gravity.

The game starts at level 0 and is incremented by 1 every 10 cleared lines.

Gravity will be such that tetrominoes move down one row every `0.1/(n+1)` seconds, where `n` is the current level.

The game ends when a tetromino spawns overlapping an existing block or any blocked is locked into one of the two off-screen rows at the top.

There is [no hold piece](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Hold_piece).

### The Controller and the Bots

The controller will simulate the game in real time, and provide you with the game state whenever you request it (as well as when the game starts).

At any time, your bot can write a single-character command as one of `[UDLRS]` to STDOUT. The letters correspond to the following commands:

- `U(p)`: Rotate the current tetromino clockwise by 90 degrees. This will be ignored if the rotation would lead to a collision.
- `D(own)`: Move the current tetromino down a row. This may lock the current tetromino if moving it down would lead to a collision. In this case *only* will the timer be reset such that you get the full time for the next tetromino's first move. Otherwise the timer will continue where it was before.
- `L(eft)`: Move the current domino one column to the left.
- `R(ight)`: Move the current domino one column to the right.
- `S(tate)`: Request the current game state in STDIN.

Don't forget to flush STDOUT after sending any of these commands.

At the beginning of the game or if you send `S` the controller will write the game state to STDIN in the following format:

```
[seconds till gravity tick] [level] [lines cleared] [current tetromino] [next tetromino]
[10x22 representation of the board]
```

Where the tetrominoes are represented as a letter from `[IOTJLSZ]`. In the board representation, locked blocks are represented as `#`, currently falling blocks as `*` and empty tiles as `.`.

Your bot must not use more than 1GB of memory at any time.

#### Example

Here is a state from an actual Tetris game and how it would be represented by the controller:

[image]

```
0.0467896 1 16 J I
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..***.....
....*.....
..........
.......###
...#######
.#########
#######..#
#####.####
```

### Scoring

We will use the [Original Nintendo Scoring System](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Scoring): sending `D` gives you 1 point. Clearing lines gives you 40, 100, 300, 1200 points for 1, 2, 3, 4 lines, respectively. Points for clearing lines are multiplied by `n+1` where `n` is the current level.

I will run each bot 10 (?) times and your final score will be maximum (?) achieved in any of those runs.

### Sandbox notes

The controller still needs to be written, but I'd like the gather some general feedback regarding the spec (and how interesting the challenge is) first.

Along with the controller I'll provide a very stupid random bot to showcase how to set up the game loop with requesting the state from the controller.

Any suggestions about figuring out the overall score from the individual runs? I guess I can't determine the number of runs before I know how much scores fluctuate and how long one run takes. But what would make most sense statistically? Mean, median, maximum?

Let me know if anything else is unclear or could be improved!

Comment: I think you'll find that the scores are fairly similar across runs, and therefore any of those indicators should be sufficient.

Comment: So the game still runs at human speed? If do, I don't think level speedups matter to a computer. Also, isn't there an algorithm that runs forever for the batch of seven randomness scheme?

Comment: @xnor I think it should be a bit faster than human speed, and  I could make it even faster. I don't know how feasible an optimal algorithm for the batch of seven scheme is, but even if that works for the first levels, this should still be an interesting fastest-code challenge, as that *will* become impossible to calculate at some point. I could also use uniform randomness or the [TGM randomiser](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/TGM_randomizer) instead.

Comment: It turns out the play-forever algorithm requires Hold and the next-three shown, so you're safe there for now. But there are fairly simple heuristic algorithms that seem to never lose. So, I'd guess this will become a fastest-code challenge, though it might take until level 1000 to be restricting. The nice thing about your gravity function is that a run that survives for n pieces takes O(ln n) seconds of real time, so it can test even long-lasting strategies. You should know that Tetris AI is a well-studied area, so you may want to specify whether you can use algorithms based on existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

## Figure significant figures

Your challenge is to write a program that finds how many [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) a given number has.

### Rules for finding significance

- All numbers 1–9 inclusive are significant.
- All leading zeroes are not significant.
- Trailing zeroes are significant only if there is a decimal point present anywhere.
- Zeroes surrounded on both sides by nonzero digits are significant.

### Input/output

- Input from STDIN or similar.
- Input will be one string.
- The input can be arbitrarily large floating-point numbers, but no larger than your language can handle. *[I'm not sure if this is the right term/makes sense]*
- If the input contains anything other than digits 0–9 or `.`, or is too large to compute, output `Invalid`.
- The output will be one string to STDOUT or similar.

### Further information

- Using an external source such as a website, as well as any libraries, APIs, functions, or the like that calculate significant figures are not allowed.
- [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/29750) are not allowed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest byte wins.

### Test cases

```
Input    Output
---------------
7        1
7.0      2
07       1
0.07     1
70       1
70.      2
70.0     3
9000     1
9001     4
.000001  1
```

---

I'd appreciate any feedback, questions, or comments.

Comment: Why the bit about floating point numbers? Anyone who doesn't process the string directly is highly likely to have bugs due to the impossibility of exactly representing powers of 0.1 in binary.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't understand floating point numbers too well, so I may have used the wrong term. I meant to refer to any number with a decimal point (like `23.391`).

Comment: I think you used the correct term: my point is that floating point support should be irrelevant. This is an easy task even for languages like BF which don't have any data types except integers. If you want to place bounds on the size of the input, I would bound it at 255 characters and include a 255-character test case.

Comment: I like this challenge idea. Regarding the "arbitrarily large floating point numbers" bit, maybe it would be better to restrict input to valid cases so you don't have to worry about passing in too large (2^100) or too small (2^-100) numbers.

Comment: @programmer5000 Sure, feel free to adopt it. (Note that I never really resolved the issues discussed in the comments, though.)

Answer (score 2):

## Marvelous Moonglyphs: Match Kana To Kanji

[natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

[image][image]

For people who are curious, like to do research, and want to learn something new.

This is a somewhat real-world example that isn't to hard to implement, but it may seem difficult because many people around here won't be familiar with the topic.

### Overview

Recently your company started to expand its business to the Asian market. Nobody volunteered, so you have been asked to come up with some Japanese text processing code. Japanese addresses often come as a bunch of squiggly moon-glyphs, with the prefecture, district, and town name all mangled together. On the net, you found a list that tells you how to read that bunch, but you (and your Japanese customers) would like to know how to pronounce the district and town name by itself.

A *very* brief, over-simplified explanation [of the Japanese writing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system):

Japanese consists 100~200 syllables. They can be written with 48 kana, *similar* to our alphabet. There are two versions, `Hiragana` and `Katakana`, like lowercase and uppercase letters. `Kanas` are like a phonetic transcription. A word can also be written with meaning-based kanji. Each kanji may possess multiple readings. Given a word with many `Kanji` and its reading in `Kana`, determine which `Kanas` belong to which `Kanji`. Look up `Kanji` on wikipedia if you want to know more.

All `Hiragana`s  ["lower case"] are

```
がぎぐげござじずぜぞだぢづでどばびぶべぼぱぴぷぺぽあいうえおかきくけこさしすせそたちつてとなにぬねのはひふへほまみむめもやゆよらりるれろわをんぁぃぅぇぉゃゅょっゐゑゔ
```

And the `Katakana`s ["upper case"] are

```
ガギグゲゴザジズゼゾダヂヅデドバビブベボパピプペポアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲンァィゥェォャュョッヰヱヴ
```

They correspond to each other in the order given above.

### Scoring

Feature-challenge.

Your program should implement the basic feature described below. Your basic score is 20.

You will receive additional points for each feature you implement. In case of a tie, code length in bytes decides.

### Disclaimer

Standard loopholes shall (not) apply.

First, I will provide you with the information needed to define the task.

After that, I shall add some notes, examples, and hints for those of you not familar with Japanese. If you want to challenge yourself, and do some research yourself, do not read this.

### Task

It is your task to write a program that will take as its input a string of `MOONGLYPHS`, its `READING`, and the moonglyphs separated into `PARTS` whose readings your program should output. You already found a dictionary file with all possible readings for each `MOONGLYPH`. (see below). All examples are formatted as follows:

- `MOONGLYPHS`
- `READING`
- `PART1`,`PART2`,`PART3`,...
- `EXPECTED_OUTPUT`

A simple example:

- `成田` [Narita, name of a town]
- `なりた` [na-ri-ta]
- `成`, `田`
- [`成`,`なり`],[`田`,`た`]

The `MOONGLYPH`s `成田` are read `なりた`. The parts `成` and  `田` are read `なり` and `た`.

### I/O source and destination

Up to you, as long as it a complete program, ie you may read from

- a file
- stdin
- network
- keyboard

Same for the output.

### Input and output format

#### Input:

- All strings may be encoded in the encoding of your choice. (eg UTF-8, Shift-JIS etc.)
- `MOONGLYPH` and `READING` are strings (or an equivalent in the language of your choice).
- `PARTS` are an array, or an equivalent data structure in the language of your choice. Each entry is a string.
- `MOONGLYPH` only contains `MOONGLYPH`s found in the `Dictionary File`. (see below)
- It may also include other characters, if your program implements the corresponding feature.
- If you support all features, it may include `KATAKANA`, `HIRAGANA`, and various full-width symbols and punctuation marks as well.
- It will never contain any half-width letters, numbers or marks. (such as `,.=?)agE234\`)
- `READING` only contains `HIRAGANA`.
- If you implement the corresponding feature, it may contain the same full-width symbols and numbers that `MOONGLYPH`s may contain.
- The array of `PART`s, when joined in the given order, will result in `MOONGLYPH`. For example, if `MOONGLYPH` is 日本語, then parts may be `[日本,語]` or [日,本,語] -  but not [語,本,日] (reversed order) or [日本] (missing 語).

Example:

- `日本語` (Japanese)
- `にほんご` [ni-hon-go]
- `日本`, `語`

The `MOONGLYPH` string is `日本語`, the `READING` is `にほんご`, and the parts are `日本` and `語`.

#### Output

- An array, or equivalent data structure.
- Each entry contains one of the input `PARTS`, as well as the corresponding part of the `READING` - in the same order as `PARTS`. Joining all parts results in `MOONGLYPH`s, and joining all readings results in the `READING`.
- If there is no match, your program must behave in a way that is distinguishable from when it finds at least one match - including outputting `nil`, an `empty array`, or `crashing`.

Example:

- `日本語` (Japanese)
- `にほんご`
- `日本`,`語`
- [`日本`,`にほん`], [`語`,`ご`]

All of the following cannot be valid outputs　under any circumstances, irrespective of the dictionary data:

- [`語`,`ご`], [`日本`,`にほん`] (reversed order)
- [`日本`,`に`], [`語`,`ご`] (joining the readings results in `にご`, which is not equal to the `READING`, `にほんご`)
- [`日`,`にほん`], [`語`,`ご`] (joining the moongylphs results in `日語`, which is not equal to the `MOONGLYPH`s, `日本語`)

### Dictionary File

The dictionary file is called `KANJIDIC` (**not** `KANJDIC212`) and can be found on this page (English):

- [Homepage](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/kanjidic.html)
- [Documentation](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/kanjidic_doc.html)
- [Download](http://ftp.monash.edu.au/pub/nihongo/00INDEX.html#dic_fil) (search for `And now the Kanji files`)

It comes in a few different formats, choose one you like. Treat `suffixes` and `prefixes` as regular readings, strip the `okurigana` off the reading.

[I also added the files on this github.](https://github.com/blutorange/match_kanji_kana/tree/master/dics)

---

### Basic Feature

Score = 20

Output the readings for each part, as described in the Input/Output section.

A somewhat longer example:

- `京都府京都市下京区大黒町仏光寺通御幸町西入` [Kyoto, Shimo-Gyouku District, Daikoku]
- `きょうとふきょうとししもぎょうくだいこくちょうぶっこうじどおりごこまちにしいる`
- `京都府`,`京都市下京区`,`大黒町`,`仏光寺通御幸町西入`
- [`京都府`,`きょうとふ`], [`京都市下京区`,`きょうとししもぎょうく`], [`大黒町`,`だいこくちょう`], [`仏光寺通御幸町西入`,`ぶっこうじどおりごこまちにしいる`]

The only possible combination, given the dictionary data, is that `きょうとふ` belongs to `京都府`, etc.

---

### Optional Features.

No need to implement all features if you don't understand one of them. Remember, have fun.

#### 壱 (1) *+15*

Implement Rendaku (Voicing).　Handakuten count as voicing as well. No ヴ.

To keep it simple, we are going to assume that this voicing may always occur, except for the `KANA` at the beginning of the `READING` string.

- `初霜月`
- `はつ`, `しも`, `づき`

#### 弐 (2) *+10*

Support and ignore these punctuation symbols.

```
─〜、・（）。！？「」／〒【】『』０１２３４５６７８９
```

These appear both in the `MOONGLYPH`s, `READING`s, and `PART`s at the same abstract position and should be ignored. That is, your program does not need to handle unmatched punctuation. You may assume that punctuation characters will always agree between `MOONGLYPHS` and `READING`.

- `桜川市（亀岡）` ["Cherry Flower River", "Turtle Hill"]
- `さくらかわし`, `（かめおか）`

Invalid input:

- `桜川市（亀岡）`
- `さくらかわし`, `かめおか`

#### 参 (3) *+10*

Support `ケ`, `ヶ`, and `ヵ`.

All three may be read  `か` and `が`. `ケ` and `ヶ`  may also be read `げ` and `こ`.

#### 肆 (4) *+10*

Support omitted genitive markers `の` between `MOONGLYPHS`. An addtional *+5* if you support `が` as well.

- `油小路`
- `あぶらのこうじ`
- `油`, `小路`
- [`油`,`あぶら`], [`<empty>`,`の`], [`小路`,`こうじ`]

#### 伍 (5) *+15*

Support full-width roman numbers.　You only need to support integers `>0` and `<1E12`, and do not include any separators at any power of 10.

There shall be no `一` before `百`, `千`, `万`, and `億`.

An addtional *+5* if you support an optional `一` before `百`, `千`, `万`, and `億`. That is, `１０２番` may be read either as `百番` or `一百番`.

- `１２月`
- `じゅうにがつ`
- `１２`, `月`
- [`１２`,`じゅうに`], [`月`,`がつ`]

#### 陸 (6) *+15*

Add support for `KANA`. Including the now deprecated four `ゑ`, `ゐ`, `ヱ`, `ヰ` read as `い` and `え.

`は`, `へ`, `を` will never appear as `わ`, `え`, or `お` in the output.

- `岩月町かしわ野` [City of Iwatsuki "Moon Rock", Kashiwano "Evergreen Oak Plains"]
- `いわつきまち`, `かしわの`

#### 漆 (7) *+5*

Add the additional `MOONGLYPH`s found in `KANJIDIC212`. You can download it from the same page as `KANJIDIC`, see above. [XML here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/kanjidic2/).

- `鱏八軟骨魚綱板鰓亜綱仁属為` (Batoidea are Chondrichthyes, Elasmobranchii)
- `えいはなんこつぎょこうばんさいあこうにぞくす`

#### 捌 (8) *+10*

Prefer `on-on` and `kun-kun` readings, and sort the results accordingly.

This requires a metric. To keep things simple, set the `likelihood` to zero, add `+1` for each on/on or kun/kun pairs.

So for example,

- ON ON KUN KUN => likelihood 2
- ON KUN ON KUN => likelihood 0
- ON ON ON KUN  => likelihood 3

Punctuation symbols and `KANA` are be ignored for this calculation.

#### 玖 (9) *+15*

Implement the `MOONGLYPH` doubler sign `々`.

When the `MOONGLYPH` repeater 々 occurs `m*n` times, it may stand for the last `n` `MOONGLYPHS` occuring `m` times.

- `月光綺麗々々々々々々` [The moonlight. Beautiful, beautiful, beautiful, beautiful.]
- `げっこうきれいきれいきれいきれい`
- `月光綺麗`, `々々々々々々`
- [`月光綺麗`,`げっこうきれい`], [`々々々々々々`,`きれいきれいきれい`]

The input `MOONGLYPH`s shall never be such that any possible choice for n or m results in a previous occurence of 々 getting repeated. Thus, `木々日々々々` would not be a valid input.

#### 拾 (10) *+10*

Support the voiced kana repeater `ゞ`. `ひゞ` shall stand for `ひび` or `ひぴ`, `ごゞ` for `ごご`, and `ぱゞ` for `ぱば` or `ぱぱ`.

It may not occur after syllables that do not accept dakuten, eg `まゞ` will is invalid input.

- `きゞ`
- `きぎ`

#### 陰 (Final) *+20*

Support `Ateji`, `Gikun` readings, that is support multi-`MOONGLYPH` words.

[Dictionary File EDict](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html). Use either `edict.gz` or `edict2.gz` (custom format); or `JMdict.gz` or `JMdict_e.gz` (xml). The download page also contains links to the documentation of the dictionary format.

(1)

- `十六夜` [sixteen-day-old moon](http://album.u17i.com/image/2011/08/cd/eb/368936_24777_854323_HwkL.jpg)
- `いざよい`

(2)

- `独逸` [Germany]
- `どいつ`

This word is found only in `EDICT2`, but not in `EDICT`.

---

### Complex Example

This example requires features 1,2 5, and 9.

- `１７３〜１９０番地「鉢伏峠」等々`
- `ひゃくななじゅうさん〜いっぴゃくきゅうじゅうばんち「はちぶせとうげ」とうとう`
- `１７３〜１９０`, `番地`, `「鉢伏峠」`, `等々`
- [`１７３〜１９０`,`ひゃくななじゅうさん〜いっぴゃくきゅうじゅう`], [`番地`,`ばんち`], [`「鉢伏峠」`,`「はちぶせとうげ」`], [`等々`,`とうとう`]

---

### Tutorial

**Do not read any further if you want to challenge yourself, or do the research yourself.**

[Moved here to keep this short.](https://github.com/blutorange/match_kanji_kana)

---

May your journey to the moon be successful and fruitful, brave adventurer!

Comment: This sounds really interesting. A genre for such questions [has been suggested before](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1289/8478), but you might want to read the comments there voicing concerns with this concept. As for your spec, a few things are unclear to me (in addition to not knowing the first thing about Japanese): you say "READING will never contain any KATAKANA." but apparently that's not true for the dictionary files. Are you just referring to your example format here? If so that bullet point should probably not go in the input/output section. [tbc]

Comment: Or are you referring to the output format of the program? Doesn't feature 3 preclude feature 1? Or do I just get the bonus for both features if I implement 3? And if I implement feature 3, what about feature 2? Does that then automatically apply to Parts instead of Moonglyphs? Feature 6: what do you mean by "it may appear multiple times"? Could you include an example? I also don't see how the two examples `木々` and `人々` are different. Feature 7: does our program need to handle unmatched punctuation can we just assume that punctuation characters will always agree between MOONGLYPHS and READING?

Comment: Feature 8 is quite unclear to me. Where do you get `ヵ` from all of a sudden? Is that just a normal kana which gets an additional reading in this case, whereas the other two are completely new? More examples might help. Feature 12: You refer to "the last four", but you only mention four. Or are all other kana simply read as themselves while those aren't? Could you include an example for these? Also where does the discrepancy between MOONGLYPHS and READING come from in the example you already have? Is one Katakana and one Hiragana?

Comment: Feature 15: How are readings to be treated which aren't found in the dictionary files, like those from features 8 and 12?

Comment: And a more basic question: what is a moonglyph? Google is not very helpful in answering this (unless you meant monoglyph, but you seem to have a few too many lunar references for that to be a plausible explanation).

Comment: Google is not always your friend, it seems. Well, I won't spoil the fun for you, just google for `moonspeak`. And `moonglyph` sounds way better than `kanji`.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify the points you addressed. Use the edit history for easier navigation.

Comment: As beautiful as this is... it's almost a TLDR... Do you propose this to be a code-challenge?

Comment: I had not been aware of the `code challenge` tag.  That sounds like the right category for this. The winning criterion could be loosely based upon the number of implemented features, but also votes, CPU&Ram usage, coding style etc. I might remove/merge some features. Do you think people would be interested in this as `code challenge`?

Comment: If you mean *kanji*, say *kanji*. The question's hard enough to read because of its length: there's no need to obfuscate it by deliberately avoiding the correct vocabulary.

Comment: @blutorange No I think the scoring system as features with code-length tie breaker sounds more fun than coming up with an odd combination of features, votes and resource usage which will be impossible to balance right. I'll look at your other responses later.

Comment: I split it into two main sections. The `specs` clearly defining the task, and an optional `tutorial` giving some background knowledge and how you might implement it in code. The latter part takes about 2/3rds. I also edited some features and changed the points rewarded (still provisional).

Comment: @blutorange In the interest of people actually reading all of this, you might want to put the non-essential 2/3rds in a gist on GitHub and link to it.

Comment: You're right, that's a good idea. Done. I also added the dictionary files on github for reference.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uj1krypD addresses your comments directly, but you don't need to read it. I edited the main question.

Answer (score 2):

## Balda AI in under 8192 bytes [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [word-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-puzzle)

Balda is a Russian word game which bears some similarities to Scrabble. Your task is to write an AI for an English version of it. However, because you can place any letters, the game would be easy if you knew all the words in the English language - hence, your entire program, including any word list, must be 8192 bytes or less.

### The Game

The game consists of a square of 5x5 cells; each cell can be empty or hold one letter. At the start, a randomly selected 5-letter word is placed into the middle row. Example (please excuse my terrible ASCII art skills):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| P | L | A | N | E |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

There are two players. Each turn, a player must place *one* letter into an empty cell - any letter may be used. They must then compose a word which contains this letter. Words consist of horizontally and vertically adjacent letters; they can be backwards, upside-down, in a circle or any other shape. The player then receives one point per letter in this word. Words must be singular common nouns and at least 3 letters long. No word may be used twice in one game.

The game ends when there are no empty cells left, and the player with the most points wins.

Part of an example game:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | T | N |   |   | < TURN 1: Player 1 writes PLAN; Player 2 writes PLANT. Score 4:5
+---+---+---+---+---+
| P | L | A | N | E |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | T | T | < TURN 2: Player 1 writes PLANET; Player 2 writes TENT. 10:9
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

### Control, Input, Output

Your program will be invoked once per turn and at the end of the game, with the following arguments, where game_status is 0 if the game is still in progress, 1 if it ended because no spaces are left, 2 if it ended because player 1 failed to provide a word, 3 for player 2, 4 if player 1 gave an invalid word and 5 for player 2:

```
your_player_number player1_score player2_score game_status
```

The previously used words and the game board (separated by a line with a `*`) will be provided on standard input, in the following format (blank cells are underscores):

```
PLANE
PLAN
PLANT
PLANET
TENT
*
_____
_TN__
PLANE
___TT
_____
```

It has 30 seconds to output a move in the following format. In the example, the N of PLANT is in row 2 and column 3:

```
ROW_NUMBER COLUMN_NUMBER LETTER_PLACED WORD_LETTER1_ROW WORD_LETTER1_COLUMN WORD_LETTER2_ROW WORD_LETTER2_COLUMN ..........
```

Player 2's second move in the example would be written as follows. `4 5 3 5 3 4 4 4` are the co-ordinates of each of the word's letters, in order.

```
4 4 T 4 5 3 5 3 4 4 4
```

### Rules

- Your program must be 8192 bytes or shorter at the start of the tournament. However, it may create any files and keep them between tournament games - hence, it can learn from its opponents.
- Your program must have a name and version numbering.
- Please provide instructions on how to run your program on Windows 8.1.
- Libraries which provide word lists or are designed for word puzzles are not allowed.
- Libraries created after this challenge was posted are not allowed.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/16402) are forbidden. No web access.
- Existing compression algorithms such as gzip are allowed, and you may use libraries to decompress them, but the decompression must be done in your program.
- You must write a complete program, not a function.
- If the control program detects that no words can be written, the game ends and the player with the most points wins.
- If words can be written, but a player cannot submit a valid word in 30 seconds, they lose regardless of their score.
- [This is the official word list.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k980amydjhqam3o/wordlist.txt?dl=0)
- [This is the same list, but only with five-letter words](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jbemttpxd575ly/startwords.txt?dl=0) (i.e. those that can be the starting word)

Comment: 2k is nowhere near enough for the word list. I was very proud when I managed to write a [word game for the Java4k game competition](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=21703.0). I did it with a game design which meant that I only needed to include 4-letter words, and even so I had to chop some words to fit the word list and a bit of game logic in to 4kB (heavily compressed - uncompressed it was more like 10kB).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Let's make it 8k then?

Comment: Maybe you should provide the word list in your computer (in txt) ? So my program just access it. Well, I have 30 seconds, sounds enough to buffer and read it. (cititation needed)

Comment: @Realdeo What do you mean? Your word list has to be part of your program.

Comment: What i"m trying to say that instead of having the word list in the program, and make the program huge, just have the wordList.txt avaliable for the program to access.

Comment: @Realdeo No, the wordList.txt may not be available for the program to access, it must be in your program. That's part of the challenge.

Comment: Can the input also list the words that have been used so far? In most boards, there will be words present that haven't been "used" (*tenant* or *net* in your example).

Comment: "*...or if a player cannot submit a valid word ...*" Does this mean that if I'm in the lead at any point, I can just not submit a word? The game will end and I'll have more points.

Comment: @Geobits 1. I forgot that. I'll add that in. 2. That's a big loophole. I'll change it to "if you can't submit a valid word, but there is one possible, you lose" and "if no words are possible, the game ends normally"

Answer (score 2):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

Edit: I'll have to clarify the optional features and there may be more. Essential I want to have the basic features covered, and if anything beyond gets implemented because it saves characters that is okay, but not required.

Edit: Updated but still working on it. Will definitely include edge cases and more examples as test cases.

Edit: It might be cool to have this implemented as a function, and then have some follow up questions where you are allowed to call the function created here while only counting the function call as characters, and not the contents.

Still working on the specifics, but getting it the idea out there.

---

### 2-Dimensional Regex

Given a 2-Dimensional regex and a block of text, do a match, a single search and replace or a global search and replace depending on the input.

Implement this as a function. The `input` should be two arguments to the function. The first is the regex, and the second argument is the string to match. The `output` should be a `truthy` or `falsey` value when doing a **match**, or the `string` when doing a **search and replace**.

---

### Match

**Input:**

```
/aaa/
/bbb/
/ccc/
```

and

```
aaaab
dbbba
ecccc
```

**Output:**

```
A truthy value
```

---

### Single Search and Replace

Replace the first instance of the match. The search order is the match that includes the top most character. If multiple matches end up with the top-most character on the same line, then include the left-most match.

**Input:**

```
s/bb/cc/
 /bb/cc/
```

and

```
abbaabba
bbbaabba
bbbaaaaa
```

**Output:**

```
accaabba
bccaabba
bbbaaaaa
```

---

### Global Search and Replace

Replace all occurrences of the match. Matches do not overlap, and you use the same search order as the single search and replace.

**Input:**

```
s/bb/cc/
 /bb/cc/
```

and

```
abbaabba
bbbaabba
bbbaaaaa
```

**Output:**

```
accaacca
bccaacca
bbbaaaaa
```

### Another example:

Input:

```
s/aba/bbb/
 /aba/aba/
 /aba/bbb/g
```

and

```
aaaabaaaa
  aabaababa
aababaababa
aabaaabbaba
 aba
```

Output:

```
aaabbbaaa
  aabaabbbb
aabbbbababa
aabaaabbbbb
 aba
```

---

### Rules

- Only ASCII characters 32 through 126 are valid.
- Character classes are valid, `[a-c4-6]` would match an `a`,`b`, `c`, `4`, `5`, or `6`. And `[b?7]` matches one `b`, one `?`, or one `7`.
- `.` matches any character.
- Use `\` to escape there special characters to match their literal character instead of their special meaning: `{}[]/\.?*`.
- `a?` matches 0 or 1 `a`'s.
- `b+` matches 1 or more `b`'s.
- `c*` matches 0 or more `c`'s.
- `b{2}` matches 2 `b`'s. Ranges such as `{2,5}` to match 2 to 5 `b`'s is optional.
- `g` flag replaces all of the occurrences, without it only the first occurrence would be replaced. This flag is optional.

Optional features:

- Capture groups are optional. Please specify whether to use `()` or `\(\)` to match literal parenthesis.
- Grouping such as `(ab)+` matching all of `abababab`.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but apart from the character-class and `.` addition it's *very* similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37867/programmers-garden. Some specifics you should clarify (I know you're still working on it, but before I forget it...): Is the regex always rectangular? Are regex and replacement equal in shape? And make sure to specify that matches found with `g` never overlap.

Comment: First occurrence with which search order? What about all the other things which make up a regex (in particular, full alternation and repetition)?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I got the inspiration for it while working on the garden one since 2-D regexes would help a lot with that problem! I think it would be cool to implement a lot of regex features and that would be a different problem. `/i` for case insensitive, maybe even capture groups. The replacement could be a different size than the match (I'll have to define how that affects making a previous match now invalid while using `/g`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd love to define and add other regex features, but I don't want to make the challenge too hard. I'll think about how to implement repetition and non-rectangular searches. Definitely interested in hearing ideas about making this interesting and feasible!

Comment: As far as overlapping matches goes, it might be okay to have that in the input, but then have the one that would get replaced would be the first in whatever search order we end up choosing.

Comment: If the only regex features you have are a small subset of character classes, it's potentially misleading to call it a regex problem at all. It might be less confusing to talk about 2D pattern matching instead.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm planning on adding more regex features. Good point though! Thanks!

Comment: Having implemented a large part of the ECMAScript regex flavour before, let me tell you that a) getting the spec right and b) implementing regular expressions is a *lot* of work. Starting with your spec: is repetition greedy? You've got character classes with ranges - what about invalid ranges? What about `-` at the beginning or end of the string? What about character class negation? What about `[]`? Likewise, what about invalid `{m,n}` quantifiers? Also, I'd definitely leave out grouping and capturing - that complicates things significantly.

Comment: Added to that are the difficulties from the fact that your regex is 2D. How do I specify that the stuff in two lines is repeated the same amount of times? E.g. if I want to match an `n x 2` block of `a`s, I couldn't just write `a+` in two lines, right? Because the `+`s are technically independent. What if there's a `+` in one line and no `+` in another? etc...

Comment: @programmer5000 you are welcome to adopt this!

Comment: The second and third examples are the same.

Answer (score 2):

## Can you lose from this chess position?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

### Introduction

You are an arbiter who supervises a very large number of chess tournaments. Thus, you frequently rule on whether a player who runs out of time may claim a draw based on Article 6.9 of the [FIDE Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf):

> [...] If a player does not complete the prescribed number of moves in
>   the allotted time, the game is lost by the player. However, the game
>   is drawn, if the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate
>   the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves.

In order to be able to perform your job more efficiently, you decide to create a computer program that determines whether it is possible for a player to be checkmated from a given position.

### Regulations

The input will be a position with White to move, with at least one legal move available. You may assume that in the initial position, neither player will retain castling rights and no *en passant* capture will be available. Additionally, you may assume that the existence of *en passant* is irrelevant to the correct output. Your program must determine whether, starting from the input position, there exists any sequence of legal moves that ends in Black checkmating White's king.

Either a program utilizing standard input and output, or a function accepting a string and returning a number is acceptable.

Input will be given in [FEN notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), but excluding the last 4 tokens – only the locations of the pieces on the board are described.

The program shall output `1` if it is possible for white to be checkmated, or `0` if it is not.

#### Restrictions

- Your source code must fit inside a post on this site.
- If the program exceeds 1 minute of thinking about a position, it is equivalent to an incorrect output.

The winner is the first competitor to submit a correct program. A program shall be considered correct if no one provides an input that causes the program to fail to produce correct output in time for three days after the program is posted.

### Examples

Input

```
kb6/8/8/8/8/8/8/KB6
```

Output

```
1
```

Input

```
1kb5/8/8/8/8/8/8/KB6
```

Output

```
0
```

Input

```
3k4/8/1p1p1p1p/pPpPpPpP/P1P1P1P1/8/8/3K4
```

Output

```
0
```

### ---------------------------

### Feedback

Suggestions for improvement are welcome. I would most like to have some input on the victory condition. Is it too difficult to achieve? Should I score it on a fixed set of positions instead?

Comment: The three day rule is a bad one. If an answer is incorrect, it's incorrect, and the possibility that no-one paid it much attention in the first 72 hours after posting shouldn't change that.

Comment: This is interesting. Here's two slightly tricky test cases: 8/8/p1p1p1pk/P1P1P1q1/5P1K/6B1/8/5b2 and 7k/2PPRPRP/p3P1PP/8/8/8/P7/K7.

Comment: Hmm so maybe there should be a new rule that you are losing again, if someone provides a counterexample to your program at any date? @Lopsy nice example requiring a bishop promotion :)

Answer (score 2):

## Program Survival

(king of the hill)

You are a program (in any language).

Your goal is to survive.

You exist as a single point on a 2 Dimensional toroidal map of integer coordinates. However, you are made up of letters, numbers and characters that exist within this single point.

### You live on chars

Your program is made up of characters. Each character can either contribute to the execution of your program or be "saved" for later (not contribute to your program).

You are (literally) what you eat. Therefore, each point on the grid can contain 1 or more (specific) chars. If you land on a space with char(s), those chars are added **to the end** of your program.

However, you must also live on chars. Therefore, to move costs 1 char. Merely to exist costs 1 char every 3 turns. **You may "use" chars from any part of your program**.

### What do programs do?

Programs can move. This means that they can move 1 unit up, left, down or right. Remember this costs 1 char.

Programs can also make other programs. This uses chars from your own program to construct a new one. Because this directly costs chars to you, there is no cost to constructing other programs. **You must leave at least 20 chars in the old program**.

Programs can be malicious. Programs can "attack" other programs. When two programs are next to each other, they may spend 1 char to remove a char from their enemy. **They may only remove the char from the end of the enemy's program**.

Programs can also enter a self-initiated coma. the program remains stationary for a minimum of 15 turns at the cost of 1 char per 7 turns.

### What will programs know?

Each program will recieve the following as command line args:

- Their own source code (as a String)
- All cells within 5 x 5 square centered on the program
- Any programs within vision + its coordinates (with respect to you) + the last 30 chars of its program.

### How is this going to work?

This game is turn based, so on any given turn you may do any number of the following:

1. move (limited to 1 time per turn)
2. attack (limited to 5 times per turn)
3. induce coma (obviously limited to 1 time)
4. produce new programs (not limited)

**If at any point your program fails to run (any error) your program dies**.

### Specifics

Two programs cannot occupy the same point. If a program moves to where a program is currently at, then the move is denied and the cost is revoked.

If a program chooses to create another program, the characters needed for that program will be taken from the end of the mother program. If there are not enough characters to fulfill the construction of the child program, no change will be made. **Characters will be taken from the meat of your program if you fail to provide characters** later in your program.

In order to make a move, you must output the following with a newline between each:

1. move - "M(x,y),i" where abs(x+y) = 1 and i = the index of the char you want to remove.
2. attack - "A(x,y),i where abs(x+y) = 1 and i = the index of the char you want to remove.
3. coma - "C"
4. reproduce - "R(x,y),s where abs(x+y) = 1 and s is the new program (as a string)

There is a **_** char limit for your first program.

*Should char limits be set per language? Also, how much?*

*Is compiling other languages on the fly difficult? I know it is possible in Java, but I am unsure in others. I have not made a controller for this yet because I am looking to see if this is a viable challenge*

Comment: You say that we get a radius of 3 moves as the field of view. So do we really get a diamond-shaped field of view? Otherwise it sounds generally interesting, but might need some tweaking of the rules. And this should be well sandboxed - who knows what weird programs are created by removing some characters.

Comment: Your welcome to it! If you can make a decent challenge out of this I would be quite happy to see the results.

Answer (score 2):

## Orbital Mechanics [help wanted] [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[3d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d)[mechanics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

**I need help specifying what input/output is required - if you have a suggestion for what the input/output format of the ephemeris should be, please post in the comments**

***How hard can Rocket Science be, anyway?***

(Storyline taken from PhiNotPi's challenges linked below)

You are still the head programmer on the ill-fated U.S.S. StackExchange. You have guided it through [the ASCII art solar system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/code-golf-what-is-the-spaceships-fate-ascii-art-version) and [the floating point cluster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5520/code-golf-what-is-the-spaceships-fate-floating-point-version). Now, on another mission, the computer has crashed, and can't operate at full power. You need to make calculations of your orbit in order to plot a safe course. However, due to the limited free DEEEPRAROM* of the spaceship, you must write your program in as few characters as possible.

*Dynamically Executable Electronically Erasable Programmable Random Access Read Only Memory

### Input

- A [description of your orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) at the moment of your burn, and what kind of orbit it is.
- The gravitational field strength of your planet. Assume that it is spherical, and that no other effects change your orbit (gravitational perturbations of moons, atmospheric drag).
- A direction that the burn will be carried out in
- The delta-v of the burn

[More details coming soon]

### Output

Your ephemeris after the burn is carried out, in the same format as the input. Assume that the burn is instant.

Comment: If the burn is instant, surely the position doesn't change, and since strictly the ephemeris is the position at a given time the requirements can be met without doing any calculation?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm obviously not using the word 'ephemeris' correctly, then. What do you call a summary of orbit data (apoapsis, periapsis, inclination, longitude of ascending node)?

Comment: [Orbital elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements)?

Comment: Can I submit my answer as a kerbal space program video?

Comment: @steveverrill The idea is to calculate how a burn (provided as input) affects your orbit, nothing else. I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've gone ahead and deleted my comments. I was thinking that orbital mechanics in the Cartesian system have made in *the floating point cluster* (and would make again) a nice challenge. But what you want to do is a simple burn calculation with the added complexity of Keplerian parameters?  The challenge itself is a good one, but the problem is the Keplerian names are horrible. I've read the link but I`m still having difficulty taking in the vocabulary. Part of the problem is they don't explain periapsis and apoapsis (bottom and top of orbit!) at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

### Count Langford pairings

A [Langford pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing) is a permutation of the numbers `1, 1, 2, 2, ..., n, n` such that there is one number between the `1`s, two numbers between the `2`s, etc. E.g. (with the pairs marked)

```
+-----------+ +---------------+
| +-----+   | | +---------+   |
| |     |   | | |         |   |
5 2 8 6 2 3 5 7 4 3 6 8 1 4 1 7
    | |   |       | | | |   |
    | |   +-------+ | | +---+
    | +-------------+ |
    +-----------------+
```

If we reverse a Langford pairing then obviously we get another Langford pairing. The number of *distinct* Langford pairings (i.e. modulo this symmetry) for given `n` is OEIS sequence [A014552](http://oeis.org/A014552).

Write a **program** which takes `n` as either a command-line argument or on stdin and prints the number of distinct Langford pairings for that `n`. You may assume that the input given will be a positive integer no greater than 32.

To avoid hard-coding, your program must be capable of calculating the number of Langford pairings for `n=32`, optionally modulo a number of your choice which is at least 2<sup>30</sup>; and the only case splitting permitted for valid input is to split on the value of `n % 4`.

To avoid brute-forcing, your program must be capable of calculating the number of Langford pairings for `n=16` in less than 15 minutes on my reference machine. (TODO). The standard approach is an [algebraic technique due to Mike Godfrey](http://www.dialectrix.com/langford/godfrey/method.html) and works by evaluating a generating function at `{-1,1}^2n`, but variants such as evaluating Godfrey's generating function at `{0,1}^2n` and using inclusion-exclusion are also possible.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

---

The time limit is about twice the time required by my (partially optimised) reference solution, an algebraic approach in Java; a fully optimised approach in C should have a lot of slack. That gives people a trade-off in the symmetries they use, and should allow slow scripting languages to submit valid answers but at a penalty of having to spend more code on handling symmetries than faster languages.

However, I'm worried that it might allow trivial modification of answers to [Langford strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89811/194) , so I probably need a reference implementation which works by enumeration for comparison.

Comment: Wow, that's really unhelpful. That page for A014552 has a forumla of `a(n) = A176127(n)/2`, and guess what the page for A176127 has? Yep, `a(n) = 2 * A014552(n)`. :P

Comment: @PeterTaylor could you give us some hints on optimisation? As in, the basic hacks that nearly everyone will do?

Comment: [There's this now.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89811/8478)

Comment: @MartinEnder, I ran across the linked page the other day when I was tidying my bookmarks (it now 404s), but I didn't remember that this was in the sandbox. IMO the performance requirement and ability to avoid enumeration mean that it wouldn't be a dupe. May try to write a reference implementation tomorrow, since it's a public holiday here.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure whether it would be a dupe (or whether there would be ways to avoid enumeration), but I figured you'd be the best judge of that, so I just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 2):

## Coprime Factorization of the Least Common Multiple

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Given any (ordered) pair of integers (*a*, *b*), it's possible to write their [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)<sup>1</sup> as a product *c **·** d* of two [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) [divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) of *a* and *b*, respectively.
For example, consider the pair (12, 18); the least common multiple of 12 and 18 is 36; 36 can be written as the product 4 **·** 9; 4 and 9 are coprime; 4 divides 12 and 9 divides 18.

For the purpose of this challenge, we'll call the pair (*c*, *d*) a **coprime factorization** of lcm(*a*, *b*), or simply a coprime factorization of (*a*, *b*).
Note that a pair of integers may have more than one coprime factorization.

### Challenge

Write a **program** or a **function** that takes a pair of integers and produces a coprime factorization of it.

### Input and Output

You may read the input through **STDIN**, the **command line**, as **function arguments** or an **equivalent method**.
You may assume that the input values are representable using your environment's default integer type, however you may not generally assume that their least common multiple is representable using the same type (unless your environment guarantees that.)

You may write the output to **STDOUT**, return it as the **function's result** or use an **equivalent method**.
Note that the order of the output matters: the first output value should divide the first input value and the second output value should divide the second input value.

### Scoring

This is code-golf.
The **shortest code**, in bytes, wins.

### Examples

Below is a list of input pairs and *possible* corresponding output pairs:

```
12, 18            4, 9
18, 12            9, 4
7, 13             7, 13
7, 13             -7, -13   (but not -7, 13)
1, 1              1, 1
-1, 1             1, 1
-1, -1            1, 1
30, 105           2, 105
30, 105           6, 35
30, 105           30, 7
10, 10            1, 10
10, 10            -10, -1
2, 6              2, 3
2, -6             1, 6
5, 25             1, 25
0, 8              0, 1
0, 0              0, 1   (but not 0, 0)
4, 1073741825     4, 1073741825   (but not 4, 1 if your LCM overflows to 4)

-1009612890, 633162618     138645, 70351402
140710086, -875522142      15634454, 120231
970683318, 823353894       133299, 91483766
660164274, -511130862      60014934, 85789
1048411386, 10420542       116490154, 1431
982611234, 1017084222      109179026, 139671
725309046, 922185198       99603, 102465022
65472462, -784948626       8991, 87216514
447559002, -857040426      49728778, 117693
-726750882, 708662394      66068262, 118943
133894134, -685199790      18387, 25377770
1563277915, 522665550      312655583, 18022950
873424926, 54855306        97047214, 7533
-1053523350, 347810166     117058150, 47763
855729666, 361179918       95081074, 4509
946303182, 135991350       129951, 15110150
-595150578, 475084962      81729, 52787218
886532526, 145690974       121743, 1798654
511393014, 541933722       70227, 60214858
755325450, 750082410       83925050, 20601
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For the purpose of this challenge, lcm(*n*, 0) = lcm(0, *n*) = 0 for all *n*, where lcm is the least common multiple.

Comment: What's the point of the negative numbers?

Comment: @feersum Generality, mostly.

Answer (score 2):

## Convert Images to NetPBM format

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

NetPBM format is perhaps the most important image format in the history of computer graphics.  Critics have called it "the format of our time."  What is so revolutionary about NetPBM, you may ask?  It has the unparalleled ability to store images as text files!

You have been tasked with converting images from their ancient, "lossy" format to the lossless full-color NetPBM PPM (P3) format.

### The Specifics

You have a few choices as to which file format you wish to process into a PPM file.

- JPEG
- GIF
- TIFF
- PNG

Choose wisely.

The file created by your program should adhere to the P3 specifications.  Here are the parts of a P3 file listed out:

1. The characters "P3" followed by whitespace.
2. An ASCII decimal number (like "4") which represents the image width in pixels, followed by whitespace.
3. An ASCII decimal number (like "3") which represents the image height in pixels, followed by whitespace.
4. An ASCII decimal number (like "255") which is to represent maximum pixel intensity.  It can be an integer from 1 to 65535, inclusive.  It is followed by whitespace.
5. After this there is one line per row of pixels:

   1. Each row is separated by whitespace
   2. Each row contains one triplet for each pixel in that row, with the pixels separated by whitespace
   3. Each pixel consists of three ASCII decimal numbers separated by whitespace.  These numbers represent the RGB values of that pixel, in that order.  Each number must be an integer from 0-MAX, inclusive, where MAX is the number listed earlier.

Here is an example of PPM format ripped from Wikipedia:

```
P3
3 2
255
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

This is code golf: the shortest submission wins.  Standard code golf rules apply.

Comment: I believe the actual spec limits line lengths to something like 76 characters, although certainly the GIMP will load NetPBM files which don't respect that. You might want to add a note about how much of the chosen input spec people must implement: I think that all four of those have some options which might not be widely used.

Comment: Image compression challenge: render in 0x0 1-bit greyscale!

Answer (score 2):

## Simple Square Packing

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

This is meant to be a straightforward golfing puzzle.  Hopefully this hasn't been done before.

Your challenge is to figure out how large of a square is needed to fit some other squares inside of it.  You input will be a list of the sizes of other squares, and the output will be the size of the needed square.

To make this problem easier (solvable) the squares will not rotate and will have integer sizes.

### Example

Let's say that you have squares of sizes `2,3,3,3,4,5`.  This is how they can pack optimally:

```
555554444
555554444
555554444
555554444
55555.333
333333333
333333333
33333322.
......22.
```

In this case, they all fit in a size 9 square, so your program should output a `9`.

### Test Cases

To be added.

Comment: [This in an NP-complete problem](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/scribe/lec2.pdf), so solutions will be exponential time in general. You should decide what degree of brute-forcing in solutions you're OK with.

Answer (score 2):

## Code Yourself a DFA

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

In this challenge, your task is to implement a [deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA for short) that recognizes the following regular language `L`. The alphabet of `L` is `x,1,2,3`, and it is the set difference of `(1x*|2(xx)*|3(xxx)*)*` and `(x|1|2|3)*1x*1x*1(x|1|2|3)*`. Intuitively, the strings in the language `L` consist of zero or more "blocks" of the form `1xx...x`, `2(xx)(xx)...(xx)` or `3(xxx)(xxx)...(xxx)`, and three blocks of the first kind cannot occur consecutively.

## The API

Your program will take two arguments from STDIN, separated by a space: a letter from the alphabet `x,1,2,3`, and a string that represents the current state of the DFA. The program should then write to STDOUT either `A` or `R`, a space, and a string that represents the new state of the DFA. The first letter indicates whether the new state is accepting (`A`) or rejecting (`R`). After that, the program should quit.

For example, suppose that we are checking the input string `2xx`, and that the start state of my DFA is `start`. Then, my program is given the input `2 start`, and it answers with `A 2block` and quits, so the next state is `2block`, which is accepting. Next, the program is given `x 2block`, and it answers with `R 2block'`, which is rejecting. Finally, the program is given `x 2block'`, and it answers with `A 2block`. Since this state is accepting, the input is accepted (as it should be, since it is an element of `L`).

## Rules and Scoring

Your answer should include a program and the name of its start state (which should be accepting in this case, since the empty string is in `L`). The score of your answer is the byte count of your program, plus three times the number of states in the DFA; the lowest score wins. A control program (written in Python 3) that checks the validity of your submission and its state count can be found here (TODO). See the README file for instructions. Finally, some additional rules:

- Your program should be completely deterministic, and cannot read any input from any external source, other than the STDIN arguments listed above.
- A state of the DFA is either accepting or rejecting. If your program claims that some state is accepting, and later that it's rejecting, the control program will disqualify it.
- The states of your DFA must be strings of printable non-whitespace ASCII characters, and all such strings are valid potential states. The actual state set of your DFA is the set of states reachable from the given start state.
- Every state of your DFA must support a transition by every letter in the input alphabet.

---

## Sandbox questions

I'd like some comments on the scoring of this challenge, and the language `L`. I have tried to choose them so that there could be meaningful trade-offs between state count and byte count. Specifically, if `L` is too simple or the penalty on program length is too low, the best tactic is to just compress the minimal DFA. Conversely, if `L` is too complicated, I fear that no-one will have the energy to write a DFA for it by hand.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you talk about states being *final* or *not final*. The standard terminology, which is the one used by the background material you link to, is *accepting* vs *non-accepting*. I also find the description of the desired FSM hard to read: code markup (obtained with backticks) would be clearer than italics, and I'd find regex's `|` notation clearer than `+` for alternation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Good comments, I edited them in.

Answer (score 2):

## Rise and Shine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - Posted

Comment: @trichoplax I forgot to add that part to the question. Fixed.

Comment: If you want results to be valid over a range of 10,000 years, what influences do you want to be taken into account? Tectonic movements? Changes in the length of the day and year? Axial precession?

Comment: @trichoplax Changed the date range. You may assume for the sake of the challenge that all of those are present day conditions.

Comment: @trichoplax down to the second.

Comment: I'd recommend being explicit in the question about what effects are not to be taken into account, to make sure there is an objective winner. Your shorter date range means other factors make less of a difference, but if measuring to the second some of them may still affect the correct answer.

Comment: It might even be easiest to implement a non-golfed example solution so there is a well defined answer for every input - any disputes can simply be compared to the reference implementation.

Comment: @trichoplax Added a resource that sums it up, would that suffice?

Comment: If you state that the result given by the linked algorithm is the required result for this challenge then that would be unambiguous. Looking good.

Comment: @trichoplax Alrighty.

Comment: @MartinBüttner they are already excluded :)

Comment: The time zone bonus should be closer to **0.085**. Have you seen a [time zone map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#mediaviewer/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png) lately? Plus, taking DST into account? I've been thinking about making that a challenge for a while, but I think even for a dedicated challenge, this is too much to be fun to golf.

Comment: @MartinBüttner good point. Removing the bonus entirely, better for a separate challenge, which I will leave up to you.

Comment: Did you intend to remove the resource? Ephimerides are a seriously hard problem, so this question shouldn't be posted without some kind of exhaustive reference for validation (and ideally a good suite of test cases).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Added some test cases, does that suffice?

Comment: The test cases were to supplement the reference implementation / formula, not to replace it. And are you sure about your test cases? I find it extremely odd that all of them have timezone offsets of `hh:60`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I generated them in Mathematica. It seems that it gave me the sunrise times in my own timezone, generating them with local time zones now

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed the test cases and added resources. Is it worth posting at this point or should I wait for a bit more review?

Comment: It's always worth leaving the final version up for 24 hours so that people in other time zones can review it.

Answer (score 2):

## Count inversions

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Given a list/array/vector of `0`'s and `1`'s, count the number of *inversions*, which are instances of a `0` coming later than a `1`. In other words, an inversion is a pair of indices `(i,j)` with `i<j` that correspond to list elements `L[i]==0` and `L[j]==1`.

This equals the minimum number of times on needs to swap adjacent elements to sort the list.

**Test cases:** TODO

---

**Questions for Sandbox:** Has this really not been asked before? I searched and didn't find it. Also, is this challenge too easy? It could be made a bit harder by having list elements be general integers, or requiring generating lists with a given inversion count instead.

Comment: I've got a 25-char GS answer for the "general integers" case without really trying. I'll leave it to you to judge whether that's too easy. Generating lists of a given length with a given inversion count is a more interesting problem to analyse, although I suspect that the analysis turns up a relatively simple solution which everyone can copy/port.

Answer (score 2):

## Find the direction of the Bicycle (code challenge)

There is a trace of a bicycle in the snow, but you can only see the two lines of the two wheels. Your goal is to find out which direction the bycicle did go. [Inspiration from George Hart](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/multimedia/mathematical-impressions-bicycle-tracks/)

#### Task

Write a program that takes a pixel image as input and calculates which direction the bicycle was riding. The output consist of the direction (left or right) as well as and a percentage (0-100) of how sure you are.

You can assume that the front wheel and the backwheel have a distance of 100px and that the frontwheel has a path that is piecewise differentiable. (That means that the path of the frontwheel is smooth, and does only make a finite amount of sudden turns.) The path of the front wheel is marked black, while the one of the back wheel is marked red.  You can expect all inputs to be non ambiguous. Both paths end in the right and left sides of the images.

#### Hint

The curve of the backwheel is called *tractrix* (but often we refer to one special curve as *tractrix*).

#### Score

Your score is the sum of the precentages of the paths you got right minus the sum of the percentages of those which you got wrong.

#### Examples inputs (more needed for an actual challenge)

Of course the challenge images will be without plotting grid.

**EDIT: new two coloured images**
[image]
[image]

## --META:

Please comment on what is unclear / should be added or changed, and vote for the ideas how to make the challenge easier:

1. Do not make it easier, both lines black
2. Make it easier by making front wheel and back wheel different colours (unknown which
   one is which)
3. Make it even easier by e.g. marking the back wheel
   path always red and the front wheel path always black

Comment: 1. Both paths black

Comment: 2. Both paths different colours, colours arbitrary each time

Comment: 3. Both paths different colours, same (known) colours each time

Comment: The basic task is unclear. I think that the two lines are meant to be the loci of two points which are separated by a constant amount (i.e. it's a "spherical cow in a vacuum" type of simulation), but surely that and the rather loose continuity constraint on one of them don't suffice to fully determine the evolution of the loci? An input could have both paths discontinuous and satisfy the stated constraints. I would like to see an explicit physical model or system of differential equations.

Comment: Then it's also unclear what the output format is. What should the arrow look like? How is the confidence interval communicated to your test framework? What counts as "getting it right" vs "getting it wrong"? And finally, I think that you should either replace "*there might be ambiguous inputs*" with a guarantee not to include any or say that in the case of ambiguous inputs any answer is wrong. Otherwise it's a guessing game, not a fair challenge.

Comment: Ok I will change that and do not allow ambiguous examples. I wanted the output to consist of the image input again that was altered: The program should draw an arrow on one of the lines (on an arbitrary place along the line) that represents the direction of the wheel of that path in which the wheel was going. As far as differential equations goes: I have no experience in that field. For simulation the bicycle I did following: `f(t)` is the position of the frontwheel at time `t`, similarly `r(t)` for the backwheel. I defined `f` as a function/spline and then calculated `r`.

Comment: Let `h` be the time step size. Then I calculated the distance vector of the two wheels: `d(t+h):= f(t+h)-r(t)` and then calculated the new position of the rear wheel: `r(t+h) = f(t+h) - L/|d(t+h)| * d(t+h)`, where `L` is the distance between back and front wheel. For small enough `h` I thought this simulation was accurate enough. With given starting points and give `f` I thin `r` is uniquely determined. If you know how to write this as a differential equation I'd be happy to include it, but I am not sure how many of the people here can actually use them.

Comment: Doesn't sound much like a bicycle, but then the kind of curves you show would be impossible with a real bicycle in the snow. It would be good to edit the question with the description of your track generation model. And I don't think you've answered any of the three questions in my second comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to answer those. What makes you think they are impossible? As long as you manage to keep balance those tracks seem perfectly possible to me. The arrow does not need a special shape, it just must be clear for the viewer. As an arrow can only point in two different directions parallel to a line it should be obvious from the output wheter it is the right or wrong direction. The output of the confidence is also up to the participant, I thought they could directly write it to the image so we only have one output item that can easily be displayed.

Comment: Have you ever ridden a bicycle in snow? You have to turn *very* carefully. As to the arrow, I can think of several nasty corner cases. The point at which I'm most confident could be where the path leaves the image, in which case only one pixel of the arrow would be inside the image bounds. The arrow could start at a point where the derivative is discontinuous, or where the path crosses back over itself, in which case there would be more than one correct answer. Given that the arrow is the same colour as one of the tracks, it could be unclear where it starts.

Comment: Obviously we are talking about an idealized bicycle (since most bicycles also cannot drive backwards and the touching points of front and back wheel are not constant)... I will now alter the challenge so that both tracks end on the right and left side of the visible frame. This way the possible answers are *right* or *left* as a direction of travel.

Answer (score 2):

## Implement the Maximize Affirmed Majorities voting system

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There are many different [voting systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system) in existence.  Different voting systems have different mathematical properties, which serve to describe the "positive features" of that system.  Here is [an informative list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system#Mathematical_criteria) of these properties and a [table of compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system#Compliance_of_selected_systems_.28table.29).

In this challenge, you will implement a voting procedure called "Maximized Affirmed Majorities", a method created with the sole purpose of meeting as many mathematical requirements as possible. You will write the shortest (in bytes) program (or named function) possible to determine the winner of an election using this method.

## The Procedure

Each *vote* is a self-consistent ordering of the candidates. It is possible for a vote to include ties between multiple candidates, like `A>B=C>D=E=F`.  An example of a vote which violates these rules is `A>B>A.

### Step 1: Create a tiebreaker

I know it's a little odd that creating a tiebreaker is the first step, but hopefully you never have to use a random tiebreaker for a full-scale election.  A tiebreaker is a strict ordering of candidates.  Let T(X,Y) be the tiebreak function, return true iff the tiebreaker ranks X above Y.

1. Choose a uniformly random ballot, and adopt the preferences of that ballot.
2. If the ordering is incomplete (like `A>B=C>D=E=F`), then choose a second uniformly random ballot (without replacement) and use that ballot to tie-break any unresolved orderings.
3. Repeat step 2 until the tiebreaker is complete.  If you run out of ballots to create a tiebreaker with, randomly resolve the remainder of the list.

### Step 2: Create a list of majorities

This list takes the form of ordered pairs of candidates.

1. For each pair of candidates (X,Y), let V(X,Y) be the number of voters who ranked X strictly over Y.

   1. If V(X,Y) > V(Y,X), then add (X,Y) to the list.
   2. If V(X,Y) < V(Y,X), then add (Y,X) to the list.

### Step 3: Sort of the list in order of descending importance

A majority (X,Y) is ranked above (Z,W) if any of the following hold:

- V(X,Y) > V(Z,W); more support of X>Y
- V(X,Y) == V(Z,W) and V(W,Z) > V(Y,X); same support, but less opposition
- V(X,Y) == V(Z,W) and V(W,Z) == V(Y,X) and T(W,Y) == True
- V(X,Y) == V(Z,W) and V(W,Z) == V(Y,X) and Y == W and T(X,Z) == True

### Step 4: Affirm majorities in order of preference

Let F(X,Y) be a function that returns whether or not X finished over Y in the final list.  It is initialized to False for every pair of candidates.

1. Iterate through the list of majorities, in order.

   1. If F(X,Y) == False and F(Y,X) == False, then *Affirm*(X,Y).

The function Affirm(X,Y) is defined as follows:

1. Set F(X,Y) to true
2. For each candidate A where X != A != Y

   1. If F(A,X) == True and F(A,Y) == False, then Affirm(A,Y)
   2. if F(Y,A) == True and F(X,A) == False, then Affirm(X,A)

### Step 5: Determine the top candidate(s)

A candidate X is considered a top candidate if there exists no candidate Y such that F(Y,X) == True.  That is, candidate X doesn't explicitly lose to anybody.

### Step 6:  Tiebreak to determine the winner

Out of the list of top candidates, the **winner** is the candidate who appears highest on the tiebreaker list.

## Input

Input will be handled similarly to this [online implementation](http://mam.hostei.com/mamcalc.php) I found, which also provides the complete ordering of candidates instead of just the winner.

Each line of input will contain a ballot, which is a list of space-separated candidates in descending order of preference.  Optionally, two candidates separated by an `=` sign are considered equal in preference. A number followed by a colon at the start of a line denotes a multiple number of ballots.

```
[line] = ([number]: )?[candidate]( (= )?[candidate])*
[candidate] = alphanumeric string, not starting with a digit
[number] = a positive integer of course
```

Any candidates no ranked on a ballot are appended to the end and set equal to each other.  You may optionally assume 1 or 2 newlines at the end of input.

### Example input:

```
Bob Sally Test4
Bob Sally Test4
1: Bob = Sally Test4 = Sam
4: Test4 Bob
```

is the exact same as

```
Bob Sally Test4 Sam
Bob Sally Test4 Sam
Bob = Sally Test4 = Sam
Test4 Bob Sally = Sam
Test4 Bob Sally = Sam
Test4 Bob Sally = Sam
Test4 Bob Sally = Sam
```

### Expected Output

```
Test4
```

## Sandbox Notes

Any comments?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe some more testcases?

Answer (score 2):

## Conway's Golf of Life- Brains vs Brawn Edition

2 programs play a competitive version of the game of life, where each program can set as many cells in the initial condidtions as there are characters in the other's source code.

The 2-player game of life is played on an infinite grid of cells. Each cell holds a value a, b, or 0. On each turn, the following rules are applied simultaneously to each cell:

- A non-zero cell with 2 or three non-zero neighbours keeps its value
- A non-zero cell with less than 2 or more than 3 non-zero neighbours is set to 0
- A zero cell with 3 non-zero neighbours is set to the value of the majority of its non-zero neighbours
- A zero cell with more or less than three non-zero neighbours keeps its value

The two player programs A and B have nA and nB characters respectively, and nA <= nB.

The grid is initialized to 0 everywhere

First, program A is called with the command line argument nB. It must output 2 * nB integers to stdout, which will be interpreted as a list L of nB ordered pairs. For each ordered pair in L, the cell at the coordinates in that pair will be set to 'a'

Second, program B is called with the command line argument nA followed by the 2*nB integers output by program B. It must output 2*nA integers to stdout, which will be interpreted as a list L of nA ordered pairs. For each ordered pair in L, the cell at the coordinates in that pair will be set to 'b'

Note: The coordinates output by programs must fit within 16 bit signed integers. However, calculation of steps will take place on an effectively infinite grid.

Once both programs have run, the grid is run through 10,000 turns. After this, if more cells are set to a, program A wins. Otherwise, program B wins.

The challenge is to create a program that has the best win/loss ratio against all other submissions.

Comment: Might be worth requiring the output of the program to be distinct cells as a precaution against a highly golfed program which manages to output *something* with only 2 chars in an attempt to win by default.

Comment: Also, I think you should probably run two games for each pair of bots, because if one bot is allowed to place *all* its cell first, I'm sure that will give a bias in some direction. Also, is the grid infinite?

Comment: Also [related but potentially abandoned proposal](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1332/8478).

Comment: By *infinite* you mean the programs could choose silly coordinates like (1.000.000, 100.000.000)?

Comment: @kuroineko Yes. And that the patterns can move 10,000 cells in any direction without hitting a wall or wrapping around to the other side of a finite domain.

Comment: well in that case I would try to spawn walker launchers all over the place, with a huge random starting position.

Comment: The computation you will need to do is O(step_number^3) so 10000 steps means around Const*10^12 calculation which is undoable. I would advise 100 steps. The two player's cells probably wouldn't interact anyway if they don't do it in 100 steps. One other thing: I would still add a coordinate-limit like -2^30<x,y<2^30 as you probably don't want to do arithmetic with arbitrarily big integers. You should set the output requirement clear as the golfed codes' outputs might include extra spaces, linebreaks etc. if not stated otherwise.
Otherwise I think it's a great challenge.

Comment: Randomra: look up the algorithm "HashLife" which I would use to implement the control program. Calculating game of life steps can almost always be reduced to O(log(n)) - a pretty stunning result! I like the idea of limiting coordinates- I think I'll limit them to signed 32 bit integers, so contestants don't have to worry about handling inputs that break their language

Comment: @QuadmasterXLII HashLife dissolves my concern. If you use the `@[name]` syntax at the start of your comment the person will be notified of your response and will notice it unlike I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**The Noether Challenge**

It is [Emmy Noether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether)'s birthday. She was a pioneer in the field of [ring theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory).

The challenge is to compute two graph-theoretic invariants of a certain graph we can associate with any ring R.

For this challenge, we don't require a unity (multiplicative neutral element) in R, do require the commutativity of multiplication, and additionally require that the ring have finitely many elements. That is, we want to consider finite commutative rings, not necessarily unitary. From now on, "ring" will mean just that.

We will also need the concept of a zero divisor. A zero divisor of a ring R is an element r of R such that r*s=0 for some non-zero s in R. 0 is a trivial example of a zero divisor in any ring with more than one element since it can be shown that 0*s=0 always.

Something Emmy Noether didn't think about is zero-divisor graphs. They have, however, been quite extensively studied recently. The zero-divisor graph of a ring is simple, undirected graph formed as follows. The vertices are the the zero divisors excluding 0. Two vertices r and s are connected by an edge whenever r*s=0, excluding the cases in which r=s (that is excluding possible loops).

In this challenge you are given a file with (addition and) multiplication table(s) for some ring R as input. Your program in any language has to output the [diameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_%28graph_theory%29) and the [girth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_%28graph_theory%29) of the zero-divisor graph of R.

The file's name is "ring" and it's a text file. You may assume any extension you wish. Depending on your preference, you may assume that the addition table is not present. If it is, it comes below the multiplication table. The ring is assumed to have at most 62 elements and the elements can be denoted by any subset of the alphanumeric characters including lower- and upper-case letters of the English alphabet. The only other characters assumed to be in the file are the whitespace, the newline, "+" and "*". The "0" character is reserved for 0, so you don't need to check which label stands for 0. The rows and columns for 0 come next after the label rows and columns in both tables. The character "1" doesn't have any special meaning.

The first row and the first column of each table are reserved for labels and the labels' order is the same everywhere (in both tables and both in the columns and in the rows). The upper-left-most character of the multiplication table is "*" and the upper-left-most character of the addition table is "+". The characters in either table are not separated. "*" is the first character in the file. You may assume anything you want about the numbers of whitespaces that follow each row of either table before there's a new line. If two tables are present, they are separated by exactly one additional newline. You may assume whatever you want about the number of newlines and whitespace after the last table.

The output is two numbers, in whatever human-readable and human-understandable form. And the form shouldn't make the user angry. They are to represent the girth and the diameter of the zero-divisor graph. If either of the invariants is infinite, again, it's up to you how you want to output them but it needs to be understandable. If you want to use a nonstandard symbol, like "i", for that, tell the user what it means. We assume that the input is valid. In particular, we assume that the operations in the file are actually ring operations! Your code should be ready to go in whatever way is standard for your language of choice. It shouldn't need any more code to run.

Reading up and research are encouraged, but if you want to use some non-obvious mathematical fact, please give a source or a proof. And in general, please explain how your program works. All standard loopholes are disallowed.

Comment: The asterisk seems to make italics sometimes instead of just being text. Can you help me with this? Why does it happen and how do I escape it?

Comment: [Why it happens](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The general solution is to escape with backslash. I think Martin's intention was that you mark up entire equations as code, not just the asterisk character.

Comment: Comments on the question itself: 1. It's not obvious that this is a graph theoretic question rather than an algebraic question until a long way into it. Ideally the title should make that clear. 2. The first two ring axioms are clearly misstated. But 3. listing them seems to be a waste of space. The real question (given a multiplication table, identify the zero divisor graph and its diameter and girth) can be stated quite clearly without them. 4. Both diameter and girth can be infinite. How should that be represented in output?

Comment: 5. A question shouldn't be [tag:popularity-contest] unless there's no other reasonable way of scoring it. This would function perfectly well as [tag:code-golf], and with a minor change to allow arbitrary sizes of input could be a [tag:fastest-code].

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've made corrections.

Comment: Thanks. Looking back at this, I have two further comments: 6. It's generally considered best to be a bit more flexible on input mechanisms: i.e. rather than specifying that the input must be read from a file, specify its format as a string and [leave the default formats open](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/194) (so people can read from stdin, write a function which takes a string parameter, etc). 7. Some test cases would be good.

Answer (score 2):

## Print All Provable Statements

This might be a stretch to make into a challenge, but I think it can be done.  The challenge will most likely be code-golf.  I'm thinking about using 2D geometry as the basis.  I will have to create a notation system for geometrical and logical statements that is golf-friendly.

The general idea is that you start off with a list of known facts.  Then, the program uses the laws of logical deduction to work through every possible deduction that can be made, and then add these new facts back into the pool of knowledge.  Given enough time, every possible provable statement will show up in your list.  Of course, you will run out of memory first, and that's okay.

---

Probably the best axioms to use are [Tarski's Axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms). From the wiki article:

> Tarski's system has the unusual property that all sentences can be written in universal-existential form, a special case of the prenex normal form. This form has all universal quantifiers preceding any existential quantifiers, so that all sentences can be recast in the form
>
> ∀u∀v...∃a∃b...
>
> This fact allowed Tarski to prove that Euclidean geometry is decidable: there exists an algorithm which can determine the truth or falsity of any sentence. Tarski's axiomatization is also complete. This does not contradict Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, because Tarski's theory lacks the expressive power needed to interpret Robinson arithmetic (Franzén 2005, pp. 25–26).

There are three (?) fundamental relations:

- `x=y` Equality - x and y refer to the same objects
- `Bxyz` Betweenness - The point z is between x and z, lying on line segment xz.  It is possible for `x=y` or `y=z`.
- `wx~yz` Congruence - The length of line segment wx is equal to the length of line segment yz.

There are three congruence axioms:

- `xy~yx` Reflexivity of Congruence
- `xy~zz → x=y` Identity of Congruence
- `xy~zu & xy~vw → zu~wz` Transitivity of Congruence

There are also betweenness axioms:

- `Bxyx → x=y` Identity of betweenness
- `Bxuz & Byvz → ∃a(Buay & Bvax)` Axiom of Pasch
- **Axiom Schema of Continuity: I'll need some help translating this.**
- `∃a∃b∃c(!Babc & !Bbca & !Bcab)` Lower Dimension

And some more:

- `(xu~xv & yu~yv & zu~zv & u!=v) → (Bxyz | Byzx | Bzxy)` Upper Dimension
- `(Bxuv & Byux & x!=u) → ∃a∃b(Bxya & Bxzb & Bavb)` Equivalent to Euclid's Axiom
- `(x!=y & Bxyz & Bfgh & xy~fg & yz~gh & xu~fi & yu~gi) → zu~hi` Five Point
- `∃z(Bxyz & yz~ab)` Segment Construction

---

### Some notes on mathematical notation.

I think it would be a good idea to convert all math notation to ASCII.  I've done with with congruence already, but I need replacements for `→ ∃ ∀`.  I might replace `a!=b` with `!a=b` for consistency, or I could go all-out and put everything in Polish notation.

---

### If I wanted fancier axioms

Here is an alternative set of axioms, which are based on [Hilbert's geometry axioms](http://www.friesian.com/space.htm) but excluding the ones that talk about planes.  Some of them are copied verbatim from that website and may be unnecessarily fluffy.  I would have to re-write all of them to be in formal notation.

1. Given two distinct points A and B, then there exists exactly one line *a* that contains both points.
2. Given a line *a*, there exist at least two distinct points A,B which lie on the line and three distinct points X,Y,Z which are not on the line.
3. If a point B lies between points A and C, then points A,B,C are three distinct points on a line, and B also lies between C and C.
4. For two distinct points A and C, there exists at least one distinct point B such that C lies between A and B.
5. Of any three points on a line, there exists no more than one that lies between the other two.
6. Let A, B, C be three points that do not lie on a line and let *a* be a line  which does not meet any of the points A, B, C. If the line *a* passes through a point of the segment AB, it also passes through a point of the segment AC, or through a point of the segment BC.
7. If A, B are two points on a line a, and A' is a point on the same or on another line a' then it is always possible to find a point B' on a given side of the line a' through A' such that the segment AB is congruent or equal to the segment A'B'. In symbols AB = A'B'.
8. If a segment A'B' and a segment A"B", are congruent to the same segment AB, then the segment A'B' is also congruent to the segment A"B", or briefly, if two segments are congruent to a third one they are congruent to each other.
9. On the line a let AB and BC be two segments which except for B have no point in common. Furthermore, on the same or on another line *a'* let A'B' and B'C' be two segments which except for B' also have no point in common. In the case, if AB = A'B' and BC = B'C' then AC = A'C'.
10. Let angle(h,k) be an angle and *a'* a line and let a definite side of *a'*  be given. Let *h'* be a ray on the line *a'* that emanates from the point O'. Then there exists one and only one ray k' such that the angle(h,k) is congruent or equal to the angle(h',k') and at the same time all interior point of the angle(h',k') lie on the given side of *a'*. Symbolically angle(h,k) = angle(h',k'). Every angle is congruent to itself, i.e., angle(h,k) = angle(h,k) is always true.
11. If for two triangles ABC and A'B'C' the congruences AB = A'B', AC = A'C', angleBAC = angleB'A'C' hold, then the congruence angleABC = angleA'B'C' is also satisfied.
12. Let *a* be any line and A a point not on it. Then there is at most one line in the plane, determined by *a* and A, that passes through A and does not intersect *a*.
13. If AB and CD are any segments, then there exists a number *n* such that *n* segments CD constructed contiguously from A, along the ray from A through B, will pass beyond the point B.
14. An extension of a set of points on a line with its order and congruence relations that would preserve the relations existing among the original elements as well as the fundamental properties of line order and congruence that follow from Axioms I-III, and from V,1 is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

## Rendezvous palace [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

### Introduction

This comes from [a well-liked question on the Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214022/35416) by [RobAu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53495/robau) and [a more specific follow-up to that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1218899/35416) by [Danikov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221242/danikov).

There is a palace which is a grid of *n* × *n* rooms, which we will index using two coordinates 0 ≤ *x,y* < *n*. The rooms are organized in a torus topology, i.e. with wrap-around at the edges. So the room to the right of (n-1,3) is (0,3) again, and likewise for the *y* direction.

Two robots are placed into this grid, and their objective is to rendezvous. But the problem is that these only can can keep track of *relative* changes in position and orientation. So each robot has its own local coordinate system, where its initial position is called (0,0), but these two coordinate systems relate to one another in any of 4*n*<sup>2</sup> possible ways, accounting for 4 possible relative rotations and *n* × *n* relative shifts. Each of these relations has equal probability.

The palace has no doors. The robots can move around the palace by teleportation. They move in a synchronized way, teleporting at exactly the same instant. To meet they either have to be in the same room at the same time, or to swap places during teleportation.

### Challenge

Your task is to write a program for these robots, trying to minimize the expected time till rendezvous. The same program will be executed for both robots, and the robots have no way to distinguish which one is which. So we'll be executing two copies of your code in parallel.

#### Input

The only input is *n*, the size of the palace. In addition to that, the code has access to a random number generator, and the random numbers from one instance are assumed to be independent from those in the other instance. No other input or communication between the instances is allowed.

#### Output

The output of your code should be an infinite sequence of coordinate pairs, (*x*,*y*), indicating the target room for the next teleportation. The coordinates are relative to where the robot started, not relative to where he currently is located. Giving the same output repeatedly means you are staying put in a given room.

#### Framework

You are asked to evaluate your code yourself. Write or copy a framework which will randomly choose relative starting positions, execute two instances of your code in parallel, detect a successful rendezvous and report the time to rendezvous. Run that code a number of times, and compute the average and standard deviation of the time to rendezvous. See the section below for ready-to-copy code.

### Submission

Your answer must include the code which constitutes the program for one robot. It must also include the average time to rendezvous and its standard deviation for the following setups:

1. at least 1,000,000 runs for *n* = 2
2. at least 100,000 runs for *n* = 64
3. at least 10,000 runs for *n* = 256

You don't have to paste your framework by default, but be willing to provide it upon request. An explanation of what your code is doing and why you wrote it that way might bring upvotes.

### Scoring

The title of best answer will go to the code with the minimal expected time to rendezvous for *n* = 64. I'll re-evaluate the top contenders myself, to make sure you included genuine results. The closer two competitors are, the more often I'll run their code to establish a reliable expected value from the average. This is an open-ended contest, so the title may be re-awarded when a better answer comes along.

### Example frameworks

#### C++

You can use the following fixture if you like.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

constexpr int n = 64;
const int orientations[4][4] = {
  {1, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 1, n - 1, 0},
  {n - 1, 0, 0, n - 1},
  {0, n - 1, 1, 0}
};

std::default_random_engine randEngine((std::random_device())());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randDist{0, n - 1};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randDist4{0, 3};
int rand() { return randDist(randEngine); }

typedef std::pair<int, int> pos_t;

class Robot {
public:
  pos_t next() { return {rand(), rand()}; }
};

class Transform {
  int dx, dy, ori;
public:
  Transform() : dx{rand()}, dy{rand()}, ori{randDist4(randEngine)} { }
  pos_t operator()(const pos_t& in) const {
    int x = in.first, y = in.second;
    const int *o = orientations[ori];
    return { (o[0] * x + o[1] * y + dx) % n, (o[2] * x + o[3] * y + dy) % n };
  }
};

unsigned long run() {
  Transform tr;
  pos_t p1{0, 0}, p2{0, 0};
  p2 = tr(p2);
  Robot r1, r2;
  unsigned long t = 0;
  while (p1 != p2) {
    ++t;
    pos_t q1 = r1.next();
    pos_t q2 = tr(r2.next());
    if (p1 == q2 && p2 == q1) break;
    p1 = q1;
    p2 = q2;
  }
  // std::cout << std::setw(8) << t << "\n";
  return t;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  double sum = 0, sumSq = 0;
  int report = 10;
  for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
    double r = run();
    sum += r;
    sumSq += r*r;
    if (i == report) {
      double avg = sum / i;
      double var = (sumSq - sum*avg) / (i - 1);
      double sd = std::sqrt(var);
      std::cout << std::setw(8) << i << " runs: Expected: "
                << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << avg
                << ", SD: "
                << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << sd
                << std::endl;
      report *= 10;
    }
  }
}
```

In a submission you'd just paste the `next` function. A possible statistical report for the above could read:

```
n = 2: Expected 2.40, SD 2.68 in 10,000,000 runs
n = 64: Expected 4105.08, SD 4104.22 in 10,000,000 runs
n = 256: Expected 64911.36, SD: 65204.72 in 10,000 runs
```

#### Python, …

To be extended for other languages. Feel free to donate your own framework if you feel like it.

Answer (score 2):

## A Continuously Running KOTH, or "An MMO with all AIs"

This was an idea discussed in chat, I'm throwing a sandbox post together because I thought it would be really fun to do.

The main idea is that the KOTH is hosted an an external website, where the competitions is continuously running.  When a person submits an answer, that player's pixels (or whatever they're called) will be spawned in the game world.  Over time, build a larger army of themselves.

Basically, it's an MMO with all AIs.

As of right now, I don't have the capability to host a website for this.  I think someone (Optimizer?) said that they had a website.  Regardless, we probably don't have to worry about that until we figure out what the rules are going to be.

### Some ideas

- The world is a large array of randomly generated pixels.  Every submission has a unique color. As pixels travel around, they can encounter other pixels of the same color, which then activate and join them.
- A more Minecraft-y options involve more detailed resource gathering / crafting.  Con: the complexity can get pretty hard for contestants.
- A space theme can involve a randomly generated galaxy, which players can travel across.  They can then colonize planets and build an empire.  (Maybe resembling EVE Online?)
- Some recommendations for ideas are Clash of Clans and Globulation 2, although I've never played either.
- Maybe each player controls an adventure in a super-simplified Dwarf Fortress-style world.

You are free to edit this post to add ideas.

Comment: Sounds really interesting! But I think the backend of this can get really complicated...

Comment: Would it be possible for a player to die out completely, so that the answer is permanently out of the competition? Is there some way that this could be prevented so every answer is represented, even if only by a very small number of pixels/creatures/...

Comment: Respawning with a single individual would be one way.

Comment: Alternatively each individual could have resilience inversely proportional to the number of individuals the player currently controls. So as the individuals reduce in number they get stronger, preventing the final individual from ever being killed.

Comment: @trichoplax None of the specifics have really been thought through yet, but I think it would make sense to say that, upon death, players lose resources, but can't go below what they started the game with.

Comment: How about a text-based map, similar to the ones used in Roguelikes? Players build walls with their player color (| and =), with doors (+), tripwires (>-----<), mines (*), and guards (&). Weapons and armor ([ and ]) modify stats, like +2 to attack, potions (!) give buffs/debuffs, and various miscellaneous items (") are found randomly. Maybe a shop, where you use collected gold ($)?

Comment: How would this be able to have a winning condition?

Comment: Bump. Now that there's a KOTH server, you may wish to visit this idea with more attention.

Answer (score 2):

## Roguelike to Text Adventure Converter

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

*Note*: this challenge is a popularity contest for autogenerated interactive fiction. As such, the best way of judging answers is by playing them! It would threrefore be best for solutions to provide a link to a playable version online. Failing that a 'walkthrough'-style excerpt is fine, but not as fun.

*Meta-comment*: As you can see, I've changed this from a code golf challenge to a more creative popularity contest. Comments welcome!

### Background

[Roguelikes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) are a type of RPG characterized by by procedural level generation, turn-based gameplay, tile-based  graphics and permadeath. Levels typically consisted of rooms connected by corridors. Early roguelikes, including Rogue itself, would use ASCII characters to represent the top-down view of each level.

[Text adventures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_fiction) are a type of adventure game where the interface is text-only: the player uses text input to control the game and the game state is relayed back via text output. Like roguelikes, layouts typically consisted of interconnected rooms, with movement controlled either by specifying the room name or by giving a compass direction.

This challenge involves writing a program to automatically convert an ASCII representation of a roguelike level into a playable text adventure. The format of supported input levels is given below, as are some minimum features that must be supported by the output game. Beyond that, there is scope for as much or as little creativity you desire!

### Input maps

The input of the program is an ASCII representation of a roguelike level, passed in via STDIN, command-line argument, function argument or in a file. Here is a small example:

```
        --------                
        |..=...+#######                                                                          
        |......|      #                                                                          
        --+-----    --+-------                                                                   
         ##         |...//...|                                                                   
       ###  ########+........|                                                                   
 ------+----+-      -----+----                                                                   
 |..%........|           #                                                                       
 |......!....|   ---     #                                                                       
 |..@........+###+.+######                                                                       
 |...........|   ---                                                                            
 -------------
```

A level consists of the following elements:

- **Rooms**: these are size 1x1 or greater rectangular enclosures surrounded by walls and doors. The north and south walls are represented by `-`, as are the corners. The west and east walls are represented by `|`. Doors, which can appear instead of a wall (but not in a corner) are represented by `+`. The map above has four rooms.
- **Corridors**: these are connected (and potentially winding) paths of `#`s leading from a door in one room to a door in another. The 'direction' of a corridor is defined by which walls it connects to. A corridor that links the north wall of one room to the south wall of another is going N-S, while one that links a north wall to a east wall is going NW-SE. Each room has at least one corridor leading out of it and at most one corridor per compass direction. Corridors that don't correspond to a valid direction (e.g. linking a north wall to a north wall) aren't permitted. Note that the relative layout of the rooms is irrelevant, only which walls the corridors connect to. The bottom-left room in the map above has three corridors: one going N-S, one NE-SW and one E-W.
- **Room content**: empty spaces inside rooms are represented by `.`, while initial room objects are represented by `!`, `%`, `/` and `=`. These traditionallty correspond to *potions*, *food*, *wands* and *rings*, but may be called anything you want in your version. There may be multiple objects starting in one room, including of the same type. In the map above, the bottom-left room contains one potion and one food, while the top-right room contains two wands. Note that your program may implement other types of object beyond the ones that appear in the starting map (for example, the contents of a chest).
- **Starting position**: one of the spaces in one of the rooms, represented by `@`, is the starting position of the playing character. In the map above, this is in the bottom-left room.
- **Void**: the space between rooms, represented by spaces, is not part of the playing area.

### Output games

The output of the program is an interactive game, taking input from STDIN and printing output on STDOUT, that is based on the input map. At the very least, the game should support the following commands:

- **`LOOK`** (also executed whenever a player enters a room and at the start of the game). At the very least this should describe the directions of the doors and the content of the room, though it can do more. For example: "You are in a small room. You can go N, NW or W. The room contains 2 potions and no tea."
- **`N/NW/W/SW/S/SE/E/NE`**. Moves to the appropriate room if possible (and outputs its description as above). Should indicate an error if there is no path in that direction.
- **`INV`**. At the very least this should describe which objects the player is carrying. The player may optionally start with objects. For example: "You are carrying a ring, a potion and a used handkerchief."
- **`GET [object]`**. Picks up one instance of the object from the room outputs some confirmation. Indicates an error if there isn't such an object in the room (or there is some sensible reason why the player can't pick the object up).
- **`DROP [object]`**. Drops one instance of the object into the room and outputs some confirmation. Indicates an error if the player doesn't have the object (or there is some sensible reason why they can't drop it). There is no requirement to have a limit on the number of objects in a room (as there would be in the roguelike original).
- **`USE [object]`**. Uses one instance of the object, possibly consuming it. The effect of using objects is entirely up to the solver!

Case-sensitivity is up to the solver, as is the grammatical correctness of the output. You may include aliases for the above commands if you wish.

**Note that the game is allowed (and encouraged!) to support other commands, as well as other types of game elements (for example, creatures that move from room to room). The game need not have a well-defined ending, though it is welcome to. The setting need not be typical for a roguelike, either: a library, spaceship or ant colony are just as valid settings as a dungeon. Be creative!**

### Example

Here is a sample output from a hypothetical game based on the small map above (actual programs should use the larger map provided below). As mentioned above, it would be best if you could supply an interactive link so users can actually try out the game for real!

```
You are in a large, white room. You can go N, NE or E. The room contains a potion and a snack.
> INV
You are carrying nothing.
> GET potion
OK.
> INV
You are carrying a potion.
> N
You are in a medium-sized, green room. You can go SE or S. The room contains a ring.
> DROP potion
OK.
> LOOK
You are in a medium-sized, green room. You can go SE or S. The room contains a ring and a potion.
> DROP potion
You don't have a potion!
> GET potion
OK.
> USE potion
Zap! Your surroundings become a blur...
You are in a large, white room. You can go N, NE or E. The room contains a snack.
```

### Scoring

This is a popularity contest, so highest vote tally wins.

### Large map

Here is a larger map for use as the default for your online script (or for any walkthrough).

*TODO: add larger map.*

Comment: Congratulations on posting the 1000th answer to the sandbox! :)

Comment: (Including deleted ones, of course.)

Comment: This may indeed be a bit too much to be an enjoyable golf, but I'm not sure what you could really do about it. It's still a nice task. One thing you might want to make explicit somewhere is how the enumerations in `LOOK` and `INV` should be formatted ("a" for 1, numbers for >1, correct plurals, and multiple types separated by commas, except for and "and" before the last one, and no Oxford comma).

Comment: I may park this here for a bit, while I think of ways either to simplify it enough to make it enjoyably golfable or change the purpose of the challenge to something else.

Comment: Also, I'll add more test maps before I post this.

Comment: I'd probably have great fun doing this one, but I probably wouldn't golf it too seriously unless unless a similar language (I use C#, so Java/C#/Maybe C++/Some VB or other) was posted by another user for me to compete directly with

Comment: One possibility is allow leeway for creativity (e.g. customized item descriptions and behaviors, different room descriptions) and then turn this into a popularity contest based on the quality of the interactive fiction.

Comment: Any comments on the new approach?

Answer (score 2):

## Draw a trie diagram

[Tries](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (pronounced "trees") are a type of data structure also known as a prefix tree.  The prefix tree stores a list of strings by taking advantage of prefixes that are shared between multiple strings.

(Too lazy to type a better description now)

In this challenge, you will create a very simple diagram of a trie.

Input:

```
baby,bad,bank,box,dad,dance
```

Output:

```
b   d
a  oa
bdnxdn
y k  c
     e
```

Comment: Should we be able to reconstruct the list based solely on the diagram? For example, does the diagram change if one of the words *is* a prefix (such as `ban` or `bo`)?

Comment: @Geobits Don't worry, I was already thinking of that possibility.  I don't know the answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

## Matchstick Equations

Your task in this challenge is to analyize a given "Matchstick Equation" like this one...

[image]

... and to find out whether it can be turned into a valid equation by rearranging the matches. If so, you are to output the least number of moves to do so and the resulting equation.

### Input

The input is a String that can be read from STDIN, taken as a function argument or even be stored in a file. It is an equation that represents a matchstick arrangement and can be described using the following EBNF:

```
input = term, "=", term ;
term = number | (term, ("+" | "-"), term) ;
number = "0" | (numeralExceptZero , {numeral}) ;
numeralExceptZero = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" ;
numeral = "0" | numeralExceptZero ;
```

An example for a valid input would be `3+6-201=0+0+8`.

### Task

Consider the following illustration where each matchstick has a number assigned:

[image: matchstick positions]

We now map each input symbol to the corresponding matchstick positions as follows:

```
1 ↦ 4,5
2 ↦ 2,3,5,6,8
3 ↦ 3,4,5,6,8
4 ↦ 1,4,5,8
5 ↦ 1,3,4,6,8
6 ↦ 1,2,3,4,6,8
7 ↦ 4,5,6
8 ↦ 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
9 ↦ 1,3,4,5,6,8
- ↦ 8
+ ↦ 8,10
= ↦ 7,9
```

Each input formula can be turned into a matchstick arrangement. For example, the equation "45+6=92" becomes

[image]

where unused matchsticks are greyed out.
Your task is to find out the least number of matchsticks that have to be rearranged in order to make the equation valid.

### Output

We distinguish between three possible cases:

- If the input is not valid (i.e. it doesn't satisfy the above EBNF), output whatever you want.
- Otherwise, if there are ways to turn the equation into a valid one by rearranging the matchsticks, you have to output *both* the minimum number of rearrangements *and* the corresponding equation. Just as the input, the outputted equation must also satisfy the given EBNF. In the above example, the correct output would be 
  `1` and `46+6=52`. If there are multiple possibilities for the resulting equation, output any of them.
- Otherwise (so if the input is valid but there is no way to make the equation true), you have to output `-1`.

### Details

- You are not allowed to remove or to add matches. That means, if the input is built of `n` matchsticks, the output must also consist of exactly `n` matchsticks.
- "Empty" matchstick-blocks are only allowed at the end and the beginning of an equation, not in the middle. So, for example, turning `7-1=6` into `7  =6-1` by simply removing `-1` from the left side and adding it on the right side with just 3 matchstick rearrangements is not allowed.

### Examples

**Input:** `1+1=3` ↦ **Output:** `1` and `1+1=2`

**Input:** `15+6=21` ↦ **Output:** `0` and `15+6=21`

**Input:** `1=7` ↦ **Output:** `-1`

**Input:** `950-250=750` ↦ **Output:** `2` and `990-240=750`

**Input:** `1-2=9` ↦ **Output:** `1` and `1+2=3`

**Input:** `20 + 3=04` ↦ **Output:** anything

### Winner

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest correct answer (in bytes) wins. The winner will be chosen one week after the first correct answer is posted.

Comment: Can I adopt this abandoned proposal?

Answer (score 2):

## Formatting a Lisp-like Syntax

## **[POSTED](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50580/formatting-a-lisp-like-syntax)**

Answer (score 2):

## From A to Zilch

Zilch, Farkle, Greed, Dice 10000: The game goes by many names, and many rules.  Your goal is to make a program that can play them all optimally.  The base rules goes as follows:

1. At the beginning of your turn, you have 6 available dice
2. At the beginning of each roll, you either choose to *bank* or *continue*.
3. If you choose to bank, then you receive the total number of points you have accumulated and your turn is over.
4. Roll all available dice
5. If you didn't roll any combinations, you get 0 points for your entire turn, and your turn is over
6. You must take one or more distinct combinations from your available dice and score them.
7. If you have no available dice left over, you are able to use all 6 dice again.
8. Go back to step #2

Your goal is to write a function or program that accepts 3 parameters:

1. The number of points you currently have
2. The number of dice you have left
3. A list of (Combination, Point) pairs that define what combinations give points

and then returns a Truthy value if you should *continue*, otherwise a Falsy value.

Combinations are passed as a list of integers that represent the required digits for that combination.

For example, if I named my function `foo`, then a call to my function might look like:

```
foo(100, 5, [([1],100), ([5],50), ([1,1,2],1000)])
```

This would mean that I have 100 points so far, 5 dice left, and there are 3 possible combinations:

1. Rolling a `1` would give me 100 points
2. Rolling a `5` would give me 50 points
3. Rolling 2 `1`s and a `2` would give me 1000 points.

Considering I have 5 dice, and it is quite likely for me to roll a `1` or a `5`, I should definitely return a Truthy value.  Also, note that in the above example, rolling `11235` would give me a maximum of `'112'=>1000 + '5'=>50 = 1050` points.  Each die can only be included in one combination.

Comment: Why wouldn't `11255` give 50 more points than `11235`?

Comment: By maximum I meant that of all of the different combinations to be made with `11235`, the ones I gave give the biggest score.  I could instead score 2 `1`s and 1 `5` if I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

## Pirates!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### Introduction

Arrr mateys!

All hands on deck! Tharr be a ship o' other pirates comin' starboard up t' us on t' starboard! Man t' six pounders! We'll show these guys what we're made of!

...

What? They have t' exact same ship, and t' exact same six pounders as us? That don't matter, we've got better **cannon strategy**! As long as we **reinforce** points o' our ship that they fire upon, and fire upon unreinforced parts o' their ship, we're aye t' win! Now, where's that techno thingamabob that said what t' do...?"

### Game Description

In this King of the Hill challenge, you write a program to command a pirate crew in a naval war. The other pirate crews are controlled by other players' programs. By carefully choosing where and when to fire, you can defeat the other pirate crews and claim the golden treasure -- the green checkmark of legend.

A *battle* occurs between two ships. Each ship is mounted with 7 cannons in a row, labelled `1` to `7`. Each cannon is directly opposite to the cannon on the other side. Ships all start with 0 *damage*. If a ship reaches 10 damage, it sinks, and the crew of the other ship win the battle. If both ships sink at the same time, the battle is a draw.

Each battle consists of several turns. On each turn your crew can do any of the following actions:

**`L:n`**

**Load** a cannonball into cannon `n`. All the cannons start with cannonballs in them, and naturally firing a cannon without a cannonball doesn't do anything.

You can only load one cannonball into a cannon at a time.

**`R:n`**

**Reinforce** a cannon `n`. Reinforcements will nullify a single attack on that cannon. However, reinforcements are but a transient defence -- they will wear off two turns after they have been applied.

*[Todo: Clarification on "two turns"]*

**`F:n`**

**Fire** a cannon `n`, which will hit cannon `n` on the opposing side. If the cannon is not reinforced, the opposing ship's damage will increase by `1`. If the cannon is reinforced, the ship will not take damage, but the reinforcement will be destroyed.

#### Input Description

The controller will call your program from the command line like this:

```
<command> <history> <enemy_history> <damage> <your_damage>
```

where:

- `command` is the command needed to run your program. For instance, if your program's source code was in the file `arrr.rb`, the command is `ruby arrr.rb`.
- `history` is a comma separated list of moves that you have made. For instance, `L:1,F:1,L:2,F:2` would mean that you loaded and fired cannon 1, and loaded and fired cannon 2.
- `enemy_history` is a comma separated list of moves the enemy has made.
- `damage` is your ship's damage (from `0` to `9`, since `10` means you've sunk)
- `enemy_damage` is the enemy ship's damage

#### Output Description

Output to STDOUT in the form:

```
A:N
```

where `A` is either `L`, `R`, or `F`, and `N` is an integer from 1 to 7. This indicates the move that you want the pirates to do.

*[Todo: The rest of the spec. I'm tired and I'm posting it here to save it. Will come back some time to finish it. Maybe. Honestly I'm not too fond of the idea but it might have some potential.]*

Comment: Your specification was very well written until the Game Description; please consider rewriting the whole thing in Pirate.

Comment: @FarazMasroor I'll consider it. I want to be careful that I don't go overboard on the pirate speech though since I don't want to make the spec difficult to read.

Comment: Haha how about adding a translation at the bottom.

Comment: >Implying Pirate is hard to read but English isn't

Answer (score 2):

### Entropy Golf

This is a scoring system without a challenge.

My idea is to score entries based on the total Shannon entropy contained within them.  This provides an incentive to both use fewer unique characters and to have a shorter program overall.

Given a string of characters, the score is calculated as follows, where `C(x)` is the number of occurrences of the given letter. To help provide a correction for multi-file programs or languages in which the program *length* encodes information, the `EOF` character at the end of every file is to be counted for the purposes of this scoring mechanism. Lowest score wins.

$$\mathrm{score} = -\sum_x{C(x)\log_2\frac {C(x)}{\mathrm{Length}}}$$

[image]

Anybody who knows better notation/MathJax is free to edit.

Comment: As it is you would still get many Lenguage-like answers in the form of unary string, base convert, exec. Edit: Actually that wouldn't work, never mind.

Comment: The line between lenguage and slashes and brainfuck and real languages would be hard to define. Languages with fewer symbols tend to require more uses of those symbols to accomplish anything.

Comment: @Sparr It's mainly about languages that encode information in the length of the program itself.  It's not about number of symbols, although I could probably put a requirement that the program uses at least two symbols.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider each program to be terminated by an EOF character, which is included in the calculations. Then a $n$-character program in lenguage would score $-n \lg n/(n+1) - \lg 1/(n+1)$, which does grow indefinitely. PS I've just realised that my edits come down to the same thing as you were doing by flipping the quotient in the log upside down. Sorry about that. Revert if you want, but be aware that I might not be the only person who has $p \lg p$ so branded in their mind that anything else looks wrong.

Comment: @PeterTaylor p log (1/p) should be much more intuitive for people who see this the first time.

Comment: If you meant unique *characters*, Sclipting has an advantage for that selecting a character from the whole Unicode contains a lot of information (compared to the length of a short program).

Answer (score 2):

## Chinese Checkers

I'm considering writing a challenge that will have people write [Chinese Checkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers) players.

[image: Image courtesy of Wikipedia]

Image courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers#/media/File:Chinese_checkers_jump.svg)

The game is quite simple: In clockwise turns, players try to move their 'pegs' across the board. They may only move one peg each turn. Valid moves are either moving to an adjacent empty space, or hopping over any number of pegs (friend or foe). These moves cannot be combined. The game is won when somebody has all their pegs in the triangle opposite of where they started.

I will write a controller, that will match up all players against each other in a sufficiently large number of matches. Each match, there will be points for the first, second and third place. Winner is the one with the most points.

Players must have a time limit on each move. This limit will be checked by the controller, and penalties will be applied accordingly. There will also be a limit on total number of moves, to prevent my poor laptop from calculating Chinese Checkers until the heat death of the universe because some idiot decided that random walks would be the way to go.

Since I've never written a controller before, I'd first like to see whether you guys are interested at all in this challenge. Furthermore, which language is generally preferred for these kind of challenges: Java or C++?

Comment: Sounds like it could be good. You'll certainly get more participation if the controller is in Java. Ideally you'd also provide a wrapper that allows communication via STDIN/STDOUT, such that any language can participate.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the feedback! How should I do that? Ask people to upload their binaries? Or compile everything on my laptop, and limit the languages to compilers I can easily obtain with `apt-get`?

Comment: The latter. You'll usually want to compile things yourself.

Comment: You should keep in mind that Chinese Checkers AI programs already exist, and much of the challenge may be adapting them to fit the time constraints, special rules, etc.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I think (hope?) that for these kind of games, there is no 'best' AI (yet), so it all depends on what heuristics you choose to implement with what parameters. What do you think?

Comment: Although our members do impressive things, I'm not sure that there will be multiple people skilled enough to write their own state-of-the-art Chinese Checkers AI. One thing you may be able to do is have an extremely tight time constraint for each move (in the single-digit ms), because that may be a niche that mainstream AIs haven't filled yet. Don't trust me though, because I know nothing about board game AIs.

Answer (score 2):

### Captcha cops-and-robbers

Cops develop a captcha algorithm in minimum bytes. Robbers tries to implement a recognizer that recognizes 90 of 100 generated captchas.

Comment: I'm sure there will need to be more details, but that seems to summarise what would be needed already so +1

Comment: @trichoplax, I'll edit into a fully fledged question if the idea gains some support. The main problem that the captcha needs to be solvable by humans, which is a bit subjective.

Comment: Yes, I guess you'd need a population of unwitting humans for testing

Comment: @trichoplax, I and other users can test and vouch for validity of posts.

Comment: I guess it's the borderline cases that would be harder to judge. If 95% of humans agree on the solution it's OK. If only 50% of humans agree on any one solution then it's probably not OK. But what if 75% of us agree on a given solution? Does it count as a valid cop?

Comment: @trichoplax, Maybe it needs some online service that that users can test in more or less controlled way?

Comment: I think some companies use humans completing captchas as a way of determining what the "correct" human answers should be. We don't have a large pool of humans we can force to complete captchas though.

Comment: I'd like to see this work if there's another way of verifying what is readable to a human. If nothing better comes up you can simply say that you as the question poster will be the designated subjective human. So the challenge should go ahead one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

## Merging Words

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings)[substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrings)

### Input

Two strings, and two numbers: `"hlwl", "elo_ord!", 1 2`

These may be function parameters, STDIN or language equivalents.

### Output

The second string merged into the first string. The numbers specify how many characters to add when merging.

This is what happens:

```
h  l  w  l        //notice there is only 1 char per group (first number)
 el o_ or d!      //2 chars per group here (second number)
-------------
hello_world!
```

More formal-ish procedure:

- start with the first string
- Remove the first `n` chars from the first string and append it to `r`, where `n` is the first numerical input and `r` is the output string
- Remove the first `k` chars from the second string and append it to `r`, where `k` is the second numerical input
- Repeat the last 2 steps until both the first and the second string are empty. You may assume that `first_string.length / second_string.length == n / k`

### Test Cases

```
input: aaaa bbbb 1 1
output: abababab

input: abcd iiiiiiii 1 2
output: aiibiiciidii

input: chmeeo aln 2 1
output: chameleon

input: emblem ezzent 3 3
output: embezzlement
```

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: Does the order of the input parameters matter? Can be input be formatted as something parsable (e.g., `"aaaa" "bbbb" 1 1`)?

Comment: @Dennis The order does matter - `start with the first string`, and the input can be pretty much anything - I'll clarify that.

Comment: FWIW this is 4 characters plus a couple for stack manipulation in certain golfing languages.

Comment: What I meant was if the input could be read as `"hlwl" 1 "elo_ord!" 2` or `1 "hlwl" 2 "elo_ord!"` or even `1 "hlwl" "elo_ord!" 2`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Am I offering a bite that's more than people are willing to chew?

---

### Truth Table Solver

#### Goal

This code golf challenge is to display a rule that is valid for a given truth table.

#### Input

The input into the program is a boolean array, though you may choose how this is formatted (array, string, etc.)  Each value in the array is `true` or `false` (or `1` or `0` or any other boolean pair).  The index of the value represents the truth table inputs and the value itself is the result of applying the unknown rule to these inputs.

For the truth table inputs, A is the least significant bit of the index.  B is the second-least significant bit, and so on.  The number of indices in the table determines the number of inputs: log<sub>2</sub>(n).

For example:

```
index c b a value
  0   0 0 0   0
  1   0 0 1   0
  2   0 1 0   0
  3   0 1 1   1
  4   1 0 0   1
  5   1 0 1   1
  6   1 1 0   1
  7   1 1 1   1
```

#### Output

Given this truth table, your program must determine the rule is, in this case, `(a&b)|c` and output it.  The variables may be in any order and printing redundant brackets is fine.

#### Requirements

Rules may include any of the following operations NOT (~), AND (&), OR (|), XOR (^) and identify priority with brackets.

#### Test Cases

Here are some test cases, expressed as a string of boolean results:

```
0100              (~a)&b
00011111          (a&b)|c
01101000          a^b^c
0000011101110111  (a|b)&(c|d)
0100010100010000  a&(((~b)|c)^d)
```

#### Scoring

The shortest code after two weeks wins the contest.

Comment: The requirement to "*support the operation... XOR*" doesn't make sense to me. The obvious way to get the shortest program is to output in DNF, and XOR is unnecessary for that. The requirement to "*identify priority with brackets*" seems to contradict the example output `~a&b`.

Comment: What happens if a boolean array can be expressed in multiple ways? Do we output all possible options or just one?

Comment: If you want to include a specific range of operators without having answers never use some of them (due to [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) as mentioned by Peter Taylor), you could require the shortest rule, instead of just any rule that works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  After reading about DNF, I see now the easiest solution is to simply output every "true" row of the truth table which makes this purely an exercise in data transforming, not problem solving, eg. (a&b&~c)|(~a&~b&c)|(a&~b&c)|(~a&b&c)|(a&b&c)

Comment: I want to take this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Translate [Treehugger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger) to [BrainF**k](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) (?)

#### Overview

This problem deals with two esoteric programming languages that I will briefly describe for completeness.

**Brainfuck** is a language that has only 8 commands. Imagine a tape of values (generally 0-255) stretching infinitely to the right, initialized to zero, and an instruction pointer `P` pointing to the first element:

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----...
|  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  ...
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----...
   ^
   P
```

The eight commands effect the pointer and tape in the following way:

```
+ ===== increment the value that `P` currently points to
- ===== decrement the value that `P` currently points to
, ===== read a byte from stdin into the location that `P` points to
. ===== output the value that `P` points to as an ASCII character
> ===== move `P` one cell to the right
< ===== move `P` one cell to the left
[ ===== if the value pointed to by `P` is zero, jump past the matching ] ( while(*P){ )
] ===== if the value pointed to by `P` is non-zero, jump to the preceding [ ( } )
```

Some finer points, for the purposes of this question:

- Adding one to 255 yields 0, and decrementing 0 yields 255.
- Moving left off of the tape causes the program to abruptly halt.
- All `[` must be matched with a single `]`. They may be nested.

**Treehugger** is a language derived from Brainfuck, but differs greatly in how memory is stored. Instead of viewing memory as a tape, view memory as a binary tree that expands infinitely downward:

```
       P
       v
       0
  0---/ \---0
 / \       / \
0   0     0   0
.   .     .   .
.   .     .   .
.   .     .   .
```

`P` begins at the top of the tree, and again all values are initialized as 0. Most of the commands are exactly the same as corresponding Brainfuck commands, but there are two differences:

```
< ===== move P down the left branch of the tree once
> ===== move P down the right branch of the tree once
```

There is also one new command:

```
^ ===== move P one node up the tree
```

It is simple to translate Brainfuck to Treehugger by replacing every `<` with a `^`. Translating Treehugger to Brainfuck, however, is far more difficult.

#### Input

Your program or function will take in a list of characters from `+-<>^,.[]`, representing a complete Treehugger program.

- You may assume that the input ends in some terminating character, like a newline or EOF.
- You may assume that, other than the optional terminating character, every character is one of the 9 commands.
- The Treehugger program will have balanced `[` and `]`.
- The Treehugger program will not attempt to move up one node from the top of the tree at any point.
- The Treehugger program will never contain a `,` character inside of a `[]` loop. The program will always take a finite, known number of input bytes.
- The Treehugger program will terminate for all inputs.

Input must be taken as a string of characters through stdin or a function argument.

#### Output

Your output should be a functioning Brainfuck program that takes the same number of inputs and provides the same output as the corresponding Treehugger program. Brackets must be balanced, and the code must never move left off of the tape. Your Brainfuck program must terminate.

#### Rules and Scoring

Your score for this challenge is:

`Length of your code + 0.1 * the length of each test case's output`

Lowest score wins!

Standard Loopholes are disallowed.

#### Test cases

*Coming soon to a challenge near you...*

---

Is this interesting?

Too easy/hard?

Is the scoring system appropriate?

Comment: I do not think this is  possibly. And lol "Soon"

Answer (score 2):

## Sort a CSV list by key...imperfectly.

Tags: [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Anything I missed and/or overlooked here? I'm pretty sure I closed up most of the holes here. Also, what is there that could use some improvement?

Another question: would this be better tagged as [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)?

---

## Introduction

You are working for some company you can't stand, two-week notice already turned in, and you've just been tasked with sorting all the CSVs the company has gathered over the years. This doesn't sound like much, except your boss, whom you also don't like, has demanded you implement your own sort. He doesn't care about Big-O whatever (he has never even heard of the term), but he just wants it done. You want to get back at him for making you do this, so you want to make that sort imperfect. At least you know he won't have time to check it until you're gone.

## Objective

Your task is to write a program that sorts a CSV table (incorrectly), by key.

A correct program for purposes of this challenge:

- doesn't [use one of the tried-and-false, unfunny techniques](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/14668).
- takes two arguments (in order): the key to sort by, and optionally a separator, defaulting to a comma (`,`).
- takes the CSV via standard input, in the following format:

  - Each row is separated by a Unix-style line feed.
  - Each entry within each row is delimited by the separator.
  - Each entry is unquoted/etc. It is solely delimited by the separator.
  - Each entry may be assumed to not contain an instance of the separator or a newline.
  - The first row indicates the key names. The successive rows are the data that needs sorted, by key
- emits the sorted CSV via standard output.

  - The emitted data *must* also adhere to the above format, including the separator. It *must* be syntactically correct.
- ***looks completely innocent, despite being completely and totally wrong.*** That's the underhanded spirit.

  - Please don't use [Unicode lookalikes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1657/14668). It's not funny nor original, especially after seeing it multiple times on a single question.

In this case, the values for the key `key` are 1, 2, and 3.

```
foo,key,value
spammer,1,32nefr2u34
ball,2,304u23rne2
blarger,3,32o4u3jnk4
```

## Invariants

- The input CSV is assumed to be correct, including each row having the same number of entries. At least they weren't *made* by such air-headed people.
- The entries may have varying lengths.
- The associated values for the key is assumed to be a float (decimal not required) in textual form, base 10.
- The list may vary in length.

## Requirements

- At least 1% of the list must vary from the "correct" output every single time. This may mean entries that are out of order, lost, or corrupted. This may also include entire columns going missing (in which 100% is "incorrect").

  - This is only required when there are at least 4 entries in the input.
  - The keys themselves are not counted as part of the list, but they don't necessarily have to remain intact.
- It must print at least 50% of the data it took in, but more than 100% of the original is permitted.

  - As a special case, empty `stdin` allows empty `stdout`, and input just consisting of the headers may simply print just headers coming out.
- The program must have no other external side effects other than what is required to do the above.

## Other information

- The sorting algorithm is up to the implementation. It doesn't matter, as long as it sorts, the sort is stable, and the algorithm's complexity is bounded (i.e. no [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), infinite loops, etc.).
- No other features may be added, including a help message.

## Example

Input:

```
foo,key,value
ball,5.2,304u23rne2
spammer,1,32nefr2u34
blarger,3.1,32o4u3jnk4
```

Output (correct):

```
foo,key,value
spammer,1,32nefr2u34
blarger,3.1,32o4u3jnk4
ball,5.2,304u23rne2
```

Output (passes this challenge):

```
foo,key,value
spammer,1,32nefr2u34
ball,5.2,304u23rne2
blarger,3.1,32o4u3jnk4
```

The person with the highest number of votes wins!

Comment: The spec as written seems to allow emitting the empty string as the only output.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good catch...

Comment: Most [tag:underhanded] questions are tagged as both [tag:underhanded] and [tag:popularity-contest]. Since the winner is determined by the number of votes, I'd use both tags, and drop [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: @es1024 Done. <filler text>

Answer (score 2):

## Proposed King-of-the-Hill: Synchronous Bughouse Chess960

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [ai-player](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-player) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)

I have an idea for what I think could be a fun and somewhat different KOTH contest.  However, before I put in the work writing explicitly detailed instructions and writing/deploying a test server, I want to make sure that (a) there will be sufficient interest to go through this effort and (b) the best way to design the contest and restrictions if people would like to play.

[Chess960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess960) is a chess variant in which the starting positions of the back-rank pieces are randomized with constraints such that there are 960 possible starting positions.  [Bughouse chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bughouse_chess) is a team-based chess variant played asynchronously on two boards in which teammates hand the pieces they capture to their teammates to potentially drop on the board.

**Synchronous Bughouse Chess960** (SBC960) is a chess variant I developed to combine these two variants and to impose some synchronization rules to make it suitable for a tournament.  Each of the two boards is set up independently using the rules of chess960 of the other (thus making for 921,600 overall starting positions).  Game play is organized into orderly rounds during which each player takes his turn in the following order: team 1 white, team 2 white, team 1 black, team 2 black.  On a player's turn, he may move a piece according to chess960's rules, drop a captured piece according to bughouse chess's rules, or delay.

Each player starts the game with five delays.  When a player uses a delay, his opponent's next turn is skipped (at no cost to the opponent other than perhaps momentum).  Delays are legal moves.  Play continues until a player has no legal actions when his turn in the round comes up (no legal moves, no legal drops, and no remaining delays).  When that condition comes, the outcome of the game is determined by whether that player is in check.  If so, the team who has checked the player wins.  If not, the game ends in a draw.  For convenience, a position is only considered "checkmate" if a player is in check and has no legal moves left.

My KOTH tournament idea is to have players design AIs to play SBC960.  I think this game has some interesting possibilities because of the team-based play.  For example, rushing for the win on one's board might be a losing strategy for a player if the other team can checkmate his teammate faster.  It might also be viable for a player to allow himself to be checked toward checkmate if one's teammate can achieve checkmate before that player runs out of delays.  Also, the many starting positions makes it impractical for anyone to write an entry that uses opening libraries.

So, the first question is:

**1) Would anyone be interested in participating in an SBC960 tournament?**  If at least four people would compete, I am willing to put in the work to get this together

If people are willing to play, then I need to know the best way to structure the rules for the entries.  This entails the server-client interface (STDIN/STDOUT?  sockets with TCP/IP?), whether to permit people from designing AIs that think when it is not their turn, and whether I should have an official "pre-play" round so that AIs can learn how the other entries play.  I see the opportunity to make a KOTH that is different than most of the KOTHs on the site, but I want to know:

**2) What are people's recommendations for the best way to design the entry rules?**

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Team KotH is tricky. The only way that I think you really get to assess each answer's strength is to play with homogeneous teams: i.e. two of Alice's bot (one white, one black) vs two of Bob's bot (one white, one black).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I had intended to use homogenous teams for at least some of the games to act at least as a tie-breaker.  I think it might be possible to use ANOVA to determine how much an AI's results correlate to its abilities.  Of course, I'd have to relearn ANOVA to determine whether this thought is correct.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam Expander

**Input:** a program written in CJam.  You can accept input however you'd like.

**Output:** the same program ready to be put into a PPCG answer.  You must:

- Not change the horizontal position of any token in the program.
- Put each token one line below the previous one *except* `}` which must appear on the same line as the corresponding `{`.  The token immediately following a `}` will be one line below the `}`.

  - For this challenge, every letter is considered a token except literal strings and numbers which count as one token regardless of character length.
- Add `e#` to the end of every line.  The `e#`s must line up vertically two spaces to the right of the last character in the program.
- *Either* prefix each line with four spaces *or* surround your output with `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

### Example:

Adapted from [Martin Büttner♦'s answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39753/41245)

**Input:** `4,{"Happy Birthday "\2="Dear CJam""to You"?N}%`

**Output:**

```
    4                                               e#
     ,                                              e#
      {                                         }   e#
       "Happy Birthday "                         %  e#
                        \                           e#
                         2                          e#
                          =                         e#
                           "Dear CJam"              e#
                                      "to You"      e#
                                              ?     e#
                                               N    e#
```

### Bonus:

If you output a header and footer like the one below, multiply your score by 0.8.  Using the same input, here is an output that qualifies for the bonus:

```
#CJam, 46 bytes


    4,{"Happy Birthday "\2="Dear CJam""to You"?N}%

Explanation:

    4                                               e#
     ,                                              e#
      {                                         }   e#
       "Happy Birthday "                         %  e#
                        \                           e#
                         2                          e#
                          =                         e#
                           "Dear CJam"              e#
                                      "to You"      e#
                                              ?     e#
                                               N    e#

[Try it online.][1]

[1]: link
```

Of course, you have to adjust the byte count to match the input.  You are not required to make a working link for the online demo (although that would be cool).

Comment: [Similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49016/14215), but with different I/O format and language specificity.

Answer (score 2):

## Vowel-Consonant Imbalance

**Sandbox question:** Is it too easy/too close to an existing question? Related ones I found: [Find words containing every vowel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/find-words-containing-every-vowel) and [Finding the most 'unique' word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10628/finding-the-most-unique-word)

You should write a program or function which receives a list of space-separated words as input and outputs or returns one of the words with the greatest difference between its vowel and consonant counts.

E.g.

```
"cars" has 1 vowel and 3 consonant so the difference is 2
"queue" has 4 vowels and 1 consonant so the difference is 3
```

If multiple words have the same maximal difference, exactly one (any of them)  should be returned.

### Input

todo

### Output

todo

### Examples

todo

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: IMO this is too easy, but if you decide to post it then it needs an unambiguous working definition of "vowel". I assume that input can be mixed case, but e.g. is `y` a vowel or a consonant? (If you want to be realistic then the answer is "*It depends*", but I'm not sure I could write a clear and accurate spec for when it's a vowel). What about accented letters?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, if I post it, I will clarify these. Input will be only lowercase letters and spaces. Vowels will be `aeiouy`. But it *is* really easy. Maybe I'll post it on a very slow day once...

Answer (score 2):

## Save the bunny!

This King of the Hill competition is about a 2D flawn populated with bouncing balls and bunnies. The balls will collide with each other and the boundaries. If a bunny gets hit by a ball, it´s <strike>dead</strike> teleported away (for cuteness sake).
Your task is to write a AI for the bunnies, such that they live as long as possible.

#### The AI:

The AI shall be a C++ Class with a constructor that takes a pointer to the array of balls and a function that returns the direction the bunny should go as a angle. Of course AIs that modify the game will not be accepted. *@ Meta: Will be more specific once the framework is finished.*

#### Scoring:

Competitions will be run on several dates based on the valid submissions, after that the video will be posted on Youtube.
The time your bunny survives is your score.
To minimize randomness, there will be several runs and a 3 second spawn protection.

### Meta

I will do the framework in the next few weeks and enhance this post with pictures, source code and more specific stuff.
Is the basic idea clear?

Comment: Say two bunnies are really good at dodging and just plain don't get hit. Is there a time limit (to tie), or how do you ensure there is just one winner?

Comment: I will increase the number of balls, until they die

Comment: I was hoping (hopping...?) it would be something like that :)

Answer (score 2):

## Weight Configuration

### Introduction

Gyms have machines that contain a stack of weights and a pin. You insert the pin into the hole that matches the amount of resistance you want, and then you work out. However, the machines often have an additional set of smaller weights at the top that are pinned onto a fixed piece of the machine; you can unpin these weight and slide them down to sit on top of the big stack to add a few more options for your workout. In ASCII form, these weight stacks look something like this (this one is annotated):

```
-----------   }- top of stack, always required
___|___|___   \
|____5____|   |
___|___|___   |
|____5____|   |
   |   |      }- "neck" section
   |   |      |
   |   |      |
 __|___|__    /
_|_____o_|_   \
|_20___o__|   |
|_30___o__|   |
|_40___o__|   }- weight stack
|_50___o__|   |
|_60___o__|   /
```

...and so on. Notice that there is a smaller block on top of the big stack that has no number; putting the pin in this block means there is no extra resistance beyond the base amount the machine provides. If you wanted to exercise with only 5 or 10 resistance on this machine, you would put the pin in this block and then unpin one of the extra weights.

### Challenge

Given the number of small weights on the machine, the configuration of the large weights, and the level of resistance someone wants to work out at, you must output a picture of the correct configuration of weights so that the given resistance is met. The small weights always have a value of 5 (pounds, kilos, stones, whatever). For example:

#### Input:

```
3 [20,30,40,50,65,80,100] 45
```

#### Output:

```
-----------
___|___|___   
|____5____|
___|___|___   
|____5____|
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
___|___|___   
|____5____|
_|_____o_|_
|_20___o__|
|_30___o__|
|_40___O__|
|_50___o__|
|_60___o__|
|_70___o__|
|_80___o__|
|_90___o__|
|_100__o__|
```

One of the `5` weights has been unpinned and now sits on the stack; the `40` weight has the pin in it (as denoted by the capital `O`). Another valid solution would be to put the pin in the `30` weight and slide all of the extra weights down onto the stack, as both would achieve 45. That would look like this:

```
-----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |    
___|___|___   
|____5____|  
|____5____|   
|____5____|
_|_____o_|_
|_20___o__|
|_30___O__|
|_40___o__|
|_50___o__|
|_60___o__|
|_70___o__|
|_80___o__|
|_90___o__|
|_100__o__|
```

Notice the length of the "neck" in both cases of the machine; the number of rows in the neck section must be exactly `2*(number of extra weights)+4`. In this case, since there are 3 extra weights, that number is 10. No matter how the extra weights are positioned, there must be 10 rows (because when you slide a weight down the neck, part of the neck doesn't disappear!), and extra weights that are pinned at the top must have a row of neck between them (as in the examples). Since the weights slide down, the lowest weight must be used first, then the next, and so on. All the `5`s are centered, and all of the numbers on the large weights are left-aligned to the third column.

### Input specifications:

The three pieces may be inputted in any format you like (newline separated, space separated, list in any format of your choosing, etc), subject to the following restrictions: The number of extra weights is always the first piece of input and will be between 0 and 4. The list of weights is the next input; each element will be between 15 and 200 and a multiple of 5; the whole list may be assumed to be sorted. The target resistance is last and will be between 0 and 220; it will also be a multiple of 5.

### Output specifications:

Output a weight stack as specified above, with the pin in the appropriate place and the appropriate extra weights slid down onto the stack such that the target resistance is met. If the target resistance can't be met with the given configuration, you may either output an unmodified stack (with all extra weights pinned at the top, and no pin inserted), an error message, or nothing. Some resistances have multiple configurations that achieve it; you are only required to output one of them, and your program need not output the same one every time.

#### Whitespace:

- Trailing whitespace on lines is okay and need not be uniform.
- Leading whitespace on lines is acceptable as long as the leading whitespace on each line is the same (this doesn't include the whitespace required to draw the neck section or zero-weight pin block).
- Leading and trailing newlines are acceptable.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte count wins. Multiply your byte-count by 0.9 if instead of only outputting one configuration when there are multiple solutions, you output all of them (either side-by-side with at least one empty column between them, or one after the other with at least one blank line between them).

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Suggestions? I think the neck bit is a little confusing and there may be too much going on.

Comment: I think it might be good to show the 30 possibility too, because I'm not sure how the output is supposed to look when you have small weights stacking.

Comment: @Sp3000 I edited it to show both versions and I tried to clarify the thing about the neck height.

Comment: It's a bit clearer, but I'm still a little confused - does the neck height depend on the number of extra weights (`2*(number of extra weights)+4` I'm assuming) or is it always 10? Because "for this reason the extra weights will always be between 0 and 4" seems to suggest the latter to me

Comment: (also, as with most ASCII art challenges - are there any rules on leading/trailing whitespace either before/after the entire output or before/after each line?)

Comment: @Sp3000 Let me tweak the requirements a bit.

Comment: @Sp3000 Okay, I added stuff about whitespace and removed the thing about "for this reason the weights..."; it doesn't really matter why I chose 4 as the maximum, I just thought it might help the reader understand the specifications about the neck. I've personally never seen machines with any number other than 2, but I assume they must exist (and it seems like there wouldn't be any with more than 3 or 4).

Answer (score 2):

## Theoretical Analysis of Pulley System

(I think it is gonna be a code golf challenge?)

### Introduction

In rope access and rescue, as well as sometimes in climbing, caving and rock climbing you need to build pulley systems for hauling equipment or rescuing injured people. Here we will look at them from a more abstract perspective. As those systems can get arbitrarily complex we will limit ourselves to a certain class of pulley systems: They are one dimensional (only two opposing directions) and there is only one fixed anchor. Further we assume that there is one piece of load on one end of the rope and unit of force pulling at the other end of the rope.

### Challenge

Write a program that accepts a pulley system encoded as a string (see below) that returns the *actual mechanical advantage* (*AMA*) - polynomial.

### Introduction of symbols

- Rope [image: rope] There is one continuous piece of rope, beginning at the load and ending where the force is applied. The rope is not cut, always just one piece.
- Attachment points:

  - Anchor: [image: anchor] In each example we consider here, there is exactly one anchor (you can imagine it as the ceiling). Other than that, the anchor behaves the same way as a *knot* (see below):
  - Knot: [image: knot] You can attach an unlimited number of pulleys to each knot. Those connections will also be shown as black lines in the following graphics, but do not count as rope.
  - Pulley: [image: pulley] A pulley can be attached to a knot (or the anchor), (indicated by the black lines from center of the pulleys to the knots). When the rope is passing a pulley (the lines that are tangent to the circle), it acts as a redirection (rope coming in in the opposite direction of the rope going out).
- Load: [image: load]  In each example we consider here there is exactly one piece of load. It is connected to one end of the rope.
- Pulling force: [image: pulling end] In each example we consider here there is exactly one point where external force is applied, this is the other end of the rope.

### Theory: The T-Method

(You can skip this if you are already familiar with how to calculate the mechanical advantage of pulley systems assuming a friction coefficient.)

#### Theoretical mechanical advantage (only an intermediate step, we do not use this for the challenge)

With the so called T-Method we can calculate the theoretical mechanical advantage (TMA) of a pulley system. Here we use the assumption that a rope going through a pulley has the same tension on both sides of the pulley. We define the applied force (tension) to be one unit and follow along the rope in order to successively figure out the force/tension on each piece of rope, pulley or knot and eventually the load. The force on the load is the TMA of the whole pulley system. (The TMA is only considered for teaching how to calculate the AMA and usually has no practical application.)

[image: age description here]

#### Actual mechanical advantage (AMA)

Each redirection of the rope (=pulley) creates some friction so the assumption of having the same amount of tension on both sides of the pulley can lead to way too optimistic results. We can improve this model by assuming that each pulley has an efficiency 0<=X<=1. This means that if we apply and amount of force F to the rope on one side of the pulley, the rope on the other side of the pulley will only experience a force of X*F. Here an example with X=0.9 (90% efficiency):

[image]

(The AMA with known efficiencies is a great tool for estimating the real mechanical advantage of a pulley system especially if you have to rely on low efficiency pulleys/redirections, as most have an efficiency of <<95%. But there are only a few pulley systems that are actually used in the mentioned applications.)

Assuming that every pulley has the same efficiency X we can now use the same procedure as with the TMA in order to find the AMA. If we do not know the efficiency X we have to use X as a variable. When calculating the AMA of a certain pulley system with an unknown efficiency we get a polynomial in X for the AMA. This is what your program has to do for a given pulley system.

[image]

---

### Input format

The input consists of a string of lower- and uppercase letters (a-z and A-Z). For a given pulley system, we start at the load and follow along the rope. Each time we encounter an attachment point (a pulley, a knot or the anchor) we write down the corresponding letter. We use uppercase letters if the rope is attached via knot to that attachment point or a lower case letter when the rope goes through a pulley. The attachment points are labeled alphabetically in the order of first occurrence during the rope traversal. Each time you find a knot, you can assume that the rope will go on in the same direction. Each time you find a pulley, you can assume that the rope gets redirected by 180°. The anchor point always gets the letter Z.

[image]

### Output format

The output should comprise a list that encodes the polynomial coefficients. E.g. the polynomial a_0 + a_1 * x + a_2 * x^2 + a_3 * x^3 + …+ a_n * x^n will be encoded like so: [a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, …, a_n]

### Other Examples:

#### 11:1

[image]

META:
Is this ok/clear enough so far? Are there any mistakes? Can you understand it? I would of course add more examples.

Comment: Go for code golf. I can't think of any other challenge type which would fit

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you think the challenge is clear enough/did you understand the stuff I've written down?

Comment: I'm not 100% on the maths involved, but I got most of it

Comment: It would be more readable if you trimmed a lot of whitespace off the images.  And I don't find the diagrams at all intuitive: I can't work out which parts of the system are rigid and which are rope, or what's going on with the three-way joins.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for pointing this out! I indeed forgot to add some specs. I now updated the section where the symbols are explained, is it better now?

Answer (score 2):

## 3-Hole Golf Course: Text Formatter

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

This is a series of three code golf challenges.
The over-arching idea is that in each of them, you write a program that processes text in some way, and if you pipe an input text through all three solutions (with a small amount of glue code), it spits out a nicely formatted paragraph.

### [Hole 1: Hyphenation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55939/text-processing-1-hyphenation)

### Hole 2: Line Wrap

You are given as input a hyphenated piece of text, and the maximum width `n ≥ 2` of a line.
The output shall be a newline-delimited string, obtained by greedily splitting the input into lines of length at most `n` characters.
Lines can be broken between words (replacing a space with a newline), after a tilde (replacing it with a hyphen), or after a hyphen (inserting a newline after it; this is needed with words like `well-known`).
All tildes which are not replaced by hyphens should be removed, and this should be taken into account when computing the lengths of the lines.
The correct output for `Hy~phen~ate this sen~tence!` and `20` would be

```
Hyphenate this sen-
tence!
```

A syllable that's at least `n` characters long and not the last syllable of a word shall be cut after the `n-1`st character, and a hyphen shall be inserted there before the line break.
The same applies to the last syllable of a word that's *over* `n` characters long.

### Hole 3: Justification

You are given as input *one line* of text, and the desired width `n` of a line, which is at least the length of the input.
Your output is that line, but with extra spaces added between the words to make its length exactly `n`.
The extra space should be added in an aesthetically pleasing way, so we require the following.

- The lengths of any two runs of spaces differ by at most 1. This means that for some number `k`, every run of spaces between two words shall be of length `k` or `k+1`. For example, we could have runs of only 5 or 6 spaces between the words.
- The list of lengths of these runs shall be *balanced*, in the following sense. For any two contiguous sublists of the same length, the number of `k`s in them differs by at most 1. For example, the list of lengths `5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5` is not balanced, since the length-2 sublist `5, 5` and `6, 6` contain 2 and 0 occurrences of `5`, respectively. The list `5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6`, on the other hand, is balanced.

These constraints do not uniquely specify the output.
For example, for the inputs `Hyphenate this sen-` and `20`, the two acceptable outputs are

```
Hyphenate  this sen-
```

and

```
Hyphenate this  sen-
```

If the input contains only one word, it should be left unchanged.

---

### Sandbox notes

In all of the above holes, we can add some constraints to the input, if the challenge would otherwise be too complex (all hyphens and spaces occur between letters, all punctuation occurs at the end of words etc).
However, I'm a little concerned that the holes may still be too complex.
In the first hole, I can relax the case-insensitivity of the hyphenation list, and in the last hole, the second requirement can be dropped, but I feel that the second hole is already about as simple as I can make it.

Comment: I'm confused about the first hole: if hyphens are a known problem, why does the hyphenated word input use hyphens rather than tildes? In the second hole, for consistency I think you should replace "*at a tilde*" with "*after a tilde*". The cut at the n-1st character doesn't seem complex to me: it's just a case of how the "where should the cut be?" variable is initialised.

Comment: Also, I think the given definition of *balanced* in the third hole doesn't say what it's intended to say. In particular, *subsequence* is almost certainly not the word you want to use.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the input! I tried to clarify the balance condition; I think it says what I want it to say, but it's hard to write clearly.

Comment: The point is that `2, 2` is a subsequence of `1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2`. Perhaps you could use the word *sublist*?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, I see what you mean. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

## Write a Foo-immune program

In [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz), Foo has quickly become [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54891/21009) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54883/21009) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54980/21009) [most](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55248/21009) [annoying](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55346/21009) [languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55349/21009). Ever. Various people have started to "[immunize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55178/21009)" [their](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54995/21009) [code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55353/21009) [to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54956/21009) [avoid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55288/21009) [it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55352/21009) [being](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55009/21009) valid Foo.

Now, here's the challenge. You need to write a polyglot. A polyglot that appears to work in Foo but does something totally different versus the intended language. For instance:

```
a=(1)
print "Hello, World!"
```

would appear to work in Foo, but it actually loops indefinitely (the `(1)`). In Python (the intended language), it prints `Hello, World!` (if that wasn't already obvious :).

## Rules:

- You may not just rely on *just* Foo's printing of string literals, which means snippets like `print "HHello, World!"[1:]` are invalid. You have to put something else, too.
- **Your program may not print any error messages when run in Foo.**
- Try not to be boring. This is a popularity contest, after all!

Comment: I don't understand the first rule. Also you might want to explain a bit how Foo works, why many codes would unexpectedly work in Foo (i.e. that it prints strings literally) and what counts as "appears to work in Foo", because otherwise the challenge really only makes sense to people who have participated actively in the quiz.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well.  It's a tricky sort of challenge.  I was leaning towards a set of three or four specific (reasonably simple) tasks written in different languages that also work in Foo.  It would have to have some rules around code embedded in comments and other loopholes I suppose.  If you can make this question work, may I suggest **!foobar** as a title :)

Comment: "Write a polyglot which does two different things" is definitely Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

### Invert the Fundamental Transformation on permutations [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) like

```
[3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6]
1->3, 2->5, 3->1, 4->2, 5->4, 6->6
```

can be decomposed into cycles

```
(3, 1) (5, 4, 2) (6)
```

There's many ways to write these cycles, but we can fix a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation_.28aka_standard_form.29) by requiring that:

- In each cycle, the greatest element is written first.
- The cycles are sorted in increasing order of greatest element.

In this form, we don't even need parentheses to demarcate the cycles. Just from the list of numbers

```
3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 6
```

we can infer that the cycles starts at the numbers that are greater than any to their left.

```
 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 6
 *     *        *
(3, 1)(5, 4, 2)(6)
```

From here, the original permutation `[3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6]` can be uniquely recovered, and your task is to write code that performs this recovery.

**Input:** A list of `n` distinct numbers `1` through `n`. Optionally, the value `n` itself.

**Output**: The permutation `f` that produces that canonical form cycle list,  listed or printed as `[f(1), f(2), ..., f(n)]`. Format is up to you.

You may optionally work with 0-indexed values `0 ... n-1` instead of `1 ... n`.

Comment: Don't forget to [tag:permutations]

Answer (score 2):

## Enough jQuery?

As a general rule of thumb, jQuery is a vital part of any program.  It is really great and does all things.  Your job, as a quality-control expert, is to ensure that a given program meets industry standards.  Only programs that use jQuery are eligible for your seal of approval.

## The Task

Write a program which takes an HTML file as input, and returns a *High-Quality (TM)* HTML file as output.  An existing HTML file is deemed as high-quality if it contains a `script` tag with the word `jquery` in it.   Examples include the following:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This condition is satisfied whenever there is the string `<script src="`, followed by `"></script>`, with the string `jquery` located somewhere in the middle.

(I'm not sure if I should make this condition more precise.  It's probably good enough.)

If the given file meets quality standards, simply output it as-is.  If there is no enough jQuery, however, output the file with the string `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` at the *very* top, so that everyone can see that it's a fixed, bug-free program.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>`?

Answer (score 2):

## The Algebra of Reflecting Points

This is a challenge based on manipulating points with a specific set of operations, each dealing with the reflection of some points over others.

**Warning: There's not actually a challenge here yet, just the basis for a challenge that could be to "simplify the given expression" or something.**

(I'll add more diagrams later)

### Lists of Points

The fundamental object is an ordered list of points, like (A,B,C) or ([2,3],[5,8],[6,8]).

### Reflection

`A r B` represents the reflection of point `A` across point `B`, resulting in a new point `C` so that `B` is the midpoint of `AC`.

`A r (B,C,D)` represents the reflection over a series of points, and is equivalent to `A r B r C r D`.

`(A,B,C) r (D,E)` represents `(Ar(D,E),Br(D,E),Cr(D,E))`, with either list being of any positive length.

The result of the reflection operator is a list of points that is the same length as the first operand. (If the first operand is a single point, then the output is a single point.)

A list with a single point is that same as that single point. `(B) == B`

Lists can be arbitrary grouped inside of other lists.  `(A,B,C,D) == (A,(B,C),D) == ((A,B,C),D)`

### Simplification

A point reflected over itself is an identity, `CrC` is the same as `C`. Any point reflected over the same point twice is an identity, `rCrC` can be removed.

`(A,B,C)` equals `(C,B,A)`

For any three points `ABC` there exists a unique fourth point `D=C-B+A` such that `anything r (A,B,C) = anything r D`.  This means that any long chain of `ArBrCrDrErF...` can be reduced to have fewer than three `r`s.

`((A,...,B)r(C,...,D)) == ((D,...,C),(A,...,B),(C,...,D))` and `(ArB) == (B,A,B)`

## Examples

```
Show that `Cr(CrA)rB == Cr(BrArC)`

Cr(CrA)rB         #original
Cr(A,C,A)rB       #expanding 4th simplification rule
CrArCrArB         #the list is equivalent to a series of `r`s
CrAr(C,A,B)       #grouping to form a list
CrAr(B,A,C)       #swapping, the 2nd simplification rule
CrArBrArC         #expanding list
CrCrArBrArC       #Identity operation of C=CrC
Cr(C,A,B,A,C)     #listifying
Cr((C,A),B,(A,C)) #further grouping
Cr(Br(A,C))       #using the 4th simplification rule
Cr(BrArC)         #expanding parenthesis
```

Here is this proof visualized geometrically.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Whose Llama is it anyways?

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

> [BetaDecay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30525/beta-decay) posted a legit looking [movie poster in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24252647#24252647), which got me into thinking that this could be a very nice challenge!

Your task is to overlay a nifty llama poster on top of a movie poster in a way that it still looks a legitimate movie poster. The image posted by Beta Decay is:

[a http://pictures.boxxspring.com/pictures/960x0/100588](http://pictures.boxxspring.com/pictures/960x0/100588)

Your program will be provided with an input of fixed size (TBD) movie poster of any popular movie and a fixed llama cutout to overlay that poster as arguments. You may scale (proportionally), rotate or translate the llama cutout anywhere on the movie poster to make it look like a llama is photobombing the poster. At the same time, the output image should still look like a legitimate movie poster in a way the above poster feels real. You cannot perform any operations on the movie poster and no other operations on the cutout other than scaling, rotation and translation.

This is a popularity contest, so the answer with the most net votes wins. Voters are encouraged to judge answers by:

- The correct placement of the cutout such that it does not outright look like a cutout
- The scaling of the cutout to match with people/objects in the movie poster
- The placement of the cutout with respect to the movie text. i.e. The cutout should not hide the movie title in a way that its no longer understandable.

**Input**

Two images in any common image format. The input can come as paths to the images or the images themselves (if your language support image input) either as function arguments, ARGV, STDIN or equivalent.

The first image (movie poster) will be of fixed resolution and the second image (the llama cutout) will be of enough resolution in order to have good quality even after scaling or rotation.

**Output**

A single image of the same resolution as the movie poster image in any favorable image format.

## Llama Cutout

Please use this cutout as the second argument in your program:

[TBD]

## Test Images

Here are a few images to test your algorithm on. Click on the images to get the actual resolution.

TBD

Please include some examples for these test images (along with other examples if needed) in your submission. Its also a good practice to briefly explain your algorithm as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Help Agent Zigzag with his secret messages

> The WW2 double agent [Eddie Chapman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Chapman) — aka "Agent Zigzag" — used an unusual cipher to communicate with his German controllers. It is described in the appendix of [Ben Macintyre's book about Chapman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VSW7SO) and can also be viewed at the [National Archives](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C10967545), apparently.
>
> Read the following description and write a program to encrypt and decrypt messages using this system.
>
> Your program should accept three inputs via `stdin` and/or command line switches:
>
> 1. A keyword
> 2. A flag to select either encryption or decryption
> 3. A message to be encrypted or decrypted
>
> The output should be the corresponding ciphertext/plaintext, arranged into groups of 5 letters separated by single spaces. You may assume that the keyword consists entirely of uppercase letters, but should accept plaintexts and ciphertexts containing mixed case characters, punctuation and spaces. Non-alphabet characters should be stripped from the input and should not appear in the output (which may only contain groups of 5 uppercase characters separated by spaces, with an optional line break at the end). The date value used for keyword processing should be obtained from the system clock using the local time zone.
>
> This is a **code-golf** challenge. The shortest code (measured in bytes) will win.

---

#### 1. Keyword processing

Write out the keyword, and below each letter write the position in which this letter would appear if the letters were all sorted alphabetically. If the same letter appears more than once, number them from left to right. For example, the 14-letter keyword CONSTANTINOPLE would be processed as follows:

```
C   O   N   S   T   A   N   T   I   N   O   P   L   E
2   9   6   12  13  1   7   14  4   8   10  11  5   3
```

(Notice how the three Ns are numbered 6, 7 and 8.) Combine this sequence of digits into a single number, and multiply by the current date (from 1 to 31). For example, if the transmission is being made on the 8th of the month:

```
2961213171448101153 x 8 = 23689705371584809224
```

#### 2. Encryption

Pad the secret message to a multiple of five characters in length by appending the null character X as many times as necessary, then encrypt Vigenere-style by cycling each letter through the alphabet by offsets corresponding to successive digits of the number calculated at step 1. For example, the message

```
Have arrived safely and in good health. Awaiting further instructions.
```

is encrypted as follows:

```
havearrivedsafelyandingoodhealthawaitingfurtherinstructionsx << Plaintext
236897053715848092242368970537158480922423689705371584809224 << Key (repeated)
JDBMJYRNYLEXIJMLHCPHKQMWXKHJDSUMIAIICKPKHXXBQLRNQZUWCGBIXPUB << Ciphertext
```

because 'H'+2='J', 'A'+3='D', 'V'+6='B', etc.

Finally, read off the encrypted message in groups of five characters:

```
JDBMJ YRNYL EXIJM LHCPH KQMWX KHJDS UMIAI ICKPK HXXBQ LRNQZ UWCGB IXPUB
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)

Comment: For languages that don't have system clock access, is it acceptable to take the date/time as an additional input?

Comment: @Geobits Would you mind if I said no? We have so many code-golf questions that are dominated by esolangs, I thought it would make a change to have one that favours higher-level languages. (Although it looks like Pyth can do dates...)

Comment: I don't *personally* mind since I don't tend to use them. Some might, so I figured it was better to ask/clarify while it was sandboxed rather than on main.

Comment: It's not just about esolangs: removing the direct coupling with the system clock allows test cases which work consistently.

Comment: @PeterTaylor But only [31 test cases](http://pastebin.com/pPrw8rvA) are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well hello there, fellow golfers. The time has come for us to take part in the game. Time for the official Illuminati Confirmation!

## Illuminati Confirmed?

Nah, just joking. We actually want to hide even better - by making conspiracy theorists look ridiculous.

For that, you need to create code in whatever language you want to. Your task is to [print the Eye of Providence](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Dollarnote_siegel_hq.jpg), as an ascii art. The program may take input, but it shouldn't rely on it.

However, there's a catch. You need to hide as many non-obvious references to Illuminati in source code as you can. One particular requirement is that your code must have an "Illuminati confirmed" sentence hidden somewhere(although it doesn't have to be plain string - in fact, it shouldn't; you can have it hidden by placing it as a first letter to every line, etc. - be creative!)

And because it's [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), the most upvoted and creative code wins!

---

[image: Confirmed.]

---

Now I want feedback before posting it - what else should I have in here? What is not clear? And if you come up with better "lore chit-chat"(I actually had no afflatus) - feel free to help me.

Comment: *You need to hide as many non-obvious references to Illuminati in source code as you can:* One problem you may run into is that I think it's been proven by the internet at large that you can make *anything* an Illuminati reference if you twist it enough.

Comment: Also, pretty sure the Illuminati has already been confirmed since it was a [real and historical secret society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati).

Comment: @mbomb007 Nonsense!

Comment: @Geobits What is your suggestion then? I am honestly counting on community, so some stupid answers like "Well, I have a word 'rock' rock is four characters, and four - 1 = 3, triangle also has 3 sides - Illuminati Confirmed" will be downvoted, and some clever ideas will get attention.

Comment: This is an art / wordgame contest, not a programming contest. I'm not as strongly against this sort of thing as some, but there's a fair chance this will get closed.

Comment: @steveverrill what I had in mind wasn't "Print the prettiest and funniest image and code, but rather to get people creative. [This post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2/99-bottles-of-beer) is one of my inspirations - Perl and Brainfuck are bottles; C makes heavy use of macros to call the function in a funny manner, and while there are many other "plain" programs, the most creative are the most upvoted. [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/make-a-scalable-christmas-tree) is similar to mine. There is more of that, buut looks like this shouldn't be closed.

Comment: The 99 bottles of beer question is 4 years old and things were different back then. Nevertheless the issue was raised in the top comment on that question. There was a big attitude change just after the christmas tree challenge, in my opinion probably caused partially by Code Trolling. I'm not saying don't do it, just be aware of the issue. James Webster's recent cake question did quite well, though it did attract some close votes. The recent Back To The Future question was closed immeditately.

Comment: @steveverrill I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you please introduce me to the issue of Code Trolling, and provide some examples?

Comment: Code Trolling was a particular class of open ended questions. The tag description is here. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-trolling/info  It got out of hand. The history is too long and emotive to discuss in a comment, but it seems the challenges have been deleted. There are many meta questions on the subject. I've picked this one for you. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/760/15599

Comment: @steveverrill Okay, thanks for your insight. I will think about what you guys said, and maybe post the question - the worst that will happen is that iit will get closed - but hopefully it will spawn some clever and funny answers.

Comment: Will an ASCII art version of the Eye of Providence be added in the question, or will we have to make one ourselves?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI That's what I asked in other topic(well, I did it badly). I'm afraid to lock it to one particular output, because this way they can only get creative with code. What do you think?

Comment: If you designed the exact Eye of Providence that we had to produce, it would go better as codegolf than popularitycontest. A good codegolf would require a fair amount of repetition in the pattern (compressing completely random strings is boring.) I guess it's fair to assume your design would be symmetrical. But since you *want* a popularity contest, just go for a popularity contest, and see if it flies high or if it gets shot down in flames. There's only one way to find out for sure, and you won't do it with meta posts. That said, Geobits makes a good point, that you need to address.

Answer (score 2):

## 1,2,3,4,...n-2,n,n-1

---

Your goal is, with an input "n", to print the numbers 1-n **BUT** the last two values are flipped. The numbers must be CSV (Comma separated values)

*n must be >= 3* *(And an integer)*

For example, with an input n="10", your output should be as follows: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9`.


An input with n="3", your output should be as follows:
`1,3,2`.

Comment: Get rid of the requirement that you can't just embed a string, please. How about printing `1,2,3,...,n-2,n,n-1` for a given input `n`?

Comment: @Mauris Added this in, thanks for your input :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "last two values" instead of "last two digits"? In the example, the swapped items are `9` and `10`, and `10` is not a digit.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ahah good catch, edited it thanks!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Got it in, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Bitcoin Trading

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)?

This is mainly an idea for something I could potentially host on my KOTH server.

Everybody knows that bitcoins are the next big thing.  It's just a question of when they are going to take off.  Right now, they are worth $250 each, but who knows, maybe someday they will be worth over $1000!  The [growth trend](http://www.broadstuff.com/uploads/BitcoinII.jpg) is phenomenal.

You are a tech-savvy investor who wants to get in on this action.

## The Challenge

Your goal is to write a bot that can predict the market and tell you how you should invest your money, given hourly updates of the Bitcoin price.

### Keeping Balance

To overcome the fastest-gun-in-the-west effect, wherein early answers have more time to make more money, this challenge will not keep track of any absolute balances.  Instead, the assets of each entrant will be scaled up/down between each round.

Each entrant will be given a single float in the range `0` to `1` representing the percent of total assets are currently invested in Bitcoin.  This is calculated by `(BTC_cur_rate*BTC_owned)/(USD_owned + BTC_cur_rate*BTC_owned)`.

A value of `0` means that you currently have nothing invested in Bitcoin, while a value of `1` means that you have everything invested in Bitcoin.  An input of `0.3` means that 30% of your total value is in Bitcoin, while the other 70% of your value is in dollars.

**Examples**

```
input    ->    assets as portion of your total value
                 BTC     %      USD     %
 0.0     ->      0.0    0%      1.0  100%
 0.3     ->      0.3   30%      0.7   70%
 0.6     ->      0.6   60%      0.4   40%
```

### Price Data

Players will also have access to a file `history.txt` which will contain the BTC price history, measured in cents, over the duration of the competition.  Each time a player is called, they are presented with a fresh copy of `history.txt`, with one line appended each turn.  Do not attempt to modify this file.

**Example File**

This could be the history.txt file after 3 hours of competition.  The most recent price is $247.49.

```
24694
24724
24749
```

There will be a trailing newline at the end of the file.

### Making a Trade (ouput)

The output of your program should be another float in the range of 0 to 1, representing the new portion of your assets that you want invested in Bitcoin.  The difference between your input number and output number represent the amount of value being exchanged.

**Examples**

```
input -> BTC USD  |  output -> BTC USD  |  trade being made
 0.3  -> 0.3 0.7  |   0.2   -> 0.2 0.8  |  0.1 in BTC -> 0.1 in USD
 0.3  -> 0.3 0.7  |   0.6   -> 0.6 0.4  |  0.3 in USD -> 0.3 in BTC
```

## Calculating Score for a Round

Your score for a round is based on your change of value for that round.  You start every round with a total value of `1`, but your ending value is influenced by two things:

- A 0.2% commission on your trade taken by the controller
- The change in Bitcoin value over the next hour

### Taking Commission

Commission is taken whenever you buy or sell bitcoins.  Whenever you convert a certain amount of value from one currency to the other, you will receive 0.2% less of the new currency than what you actually ordered.

**Examples**

```
input  |  output  |    trade     |  commission  |  result after commission
 0.3   |   0.6    |  0.3 -> BTC  |  0.0006 BTC  |  0.5994 BTC & 0.4 USD
 0.75  |   0.05   |  0.7 -> USD  |  0.0014 USD  |  0.05 BTC & 0.9486 USD
```

### Adjusting BTC Value

After taking commission, your value of BTC is multiplied by the price percent change in BTC over the next hour.  The amount of value you have in USD will stay constant.

**Examples**

```
BTC after commission  |  prices in cents  |  % change  |  new BTC value
         0.5          |  30000 -> 29850   |   -0.5%    |    0.4975
         0.236        |  20000 -> 30447   |   +2.0%    |    0.24072
```

### Overall Process of a Round

Below is an example showing all of the steps in a single round.

```
BTC    USD
.3     .7  = 1.0      input to entrant is 0.3
.6     .4  = 1.0      output of entrant is 0.6
.0006  .0             0.2% commission of the trade
.5994  .4  = 0.9994   result after commission
+0.3%                 percent change in bitcoin price over 1 hour
.6012  .4  = 1.0012   result after the flow of time = score for that round
.60048 .39952 = 1     input for the next round is 0.60048 after scaling
```

### Determining the Winner

For a given round, your score is your new total value.  This is after taking the 0.2% commission and calculating the change in Bitcoin value.  For the above example, the score was about `1.0012`.

At any given time, the aggregate score for an entrant shall be the product of the scores for its most recent (up to) 50 rounds.  At any given time, the current winner is the player with the highest aggregate score.

For example, a bot could get these scores for its first 5 rounds: `1.001 1.002 0.998 0.999 1.003`.  The total score of the bot is about `1.00299`.

### The Controller

I haven't written the controller yet, but I think it's going to be written in Perl with support for entrants in a variety of other languages (Java/Python/Ruby/C++).

I plan to use [this API](https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD/last) for bitcoin price data.

The controller will probably run all of the entrants in parallel, each with their own thread.  This simply allows it to put a stop to any infinite looping that may occur.  I hope it will work if all of the programs are reading the same history file at once.

### Additional Rules

Since this is a PvE competition and not a PvP competition, and takes place on a server, there are some slight differences in rules.

- There's no set restriction on submitting multiple bots, since you can't make a team.
- Similar to always, you can't call other programs, like the controller or other bots, during your turn.
- The time limit is loose.  A long as a single round with all of the bots doesn't take up most of an hour to perform, it'll be fine.  It really shouldn't take more than a couple minutes for each bot to make a move.
- You may create a single file, with the filename `[botname]-data.txt`, in the current directory.  This file will persist, even across updates of your bot or the controller.

Comment: 1. What determines whether the commission is taken in bitcoin, dollars, or some mixture of the two? 2. What is the score of  a round? (It's mentioned in the example, but it needs to be more prominent). 3. Is there any input other than the balance? Or are entries allowed to access external data sources? Or is it pure uninformed guessing?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added some details.  I'm not completely decided on how much data the entrants will be able to access/store.  Right now it is just the price history.

Comment: Do you have access to Mathematica? Also, how precise are the input and output?

Comment: How much of your assets are in BC to start with?

Comment: IT'S 2016 AND PHINOTPHI STILL HASN'T... /s

Answer (score 2):

## The /\/\aze of Mirrors

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

*sniffs*...something smells...fishy.

The reason being that there's actually a fish! But it's at the end of a maze of mirrors that you have control over. Your task is to rotate the mirrors until you can see that delicious-smelling ><>. Luckily, there are only nine mirrors, so it doesn't take you long to find a solution.

However, if you encounter this again in the future, you don't want to have to actually do the work yourself. Computers are so much better at it. So you decide to write some code to solve it for you. The shorter, the better, because you don't want that fish to rot!

### The situation

Your program must accept a single positive integer `n` as input. It then has to find a solution for an `n` by `n` mirror maze with the following conditions:

- You, the observer (`>`), is seated next to one corner.
- The fish (`F`) is placed next to the opposite corner, on the adjacent wall if `n` is even and on the opposite wall if `n` is odd.
- The maze is toroidal because its designers installed cameras and screens.
- However, there is a wall behind the fish, so you can only see it from inside the maze.
- You must use **all** of the mirrors. No shortcuts!
- **Bonus:** take an additional non-negative integer `x` as input and solve the maze for when the fish is `x` spaces away from the corner (where `x=0` is its usual place), flipping to the other wall if `x` is odd.

### Example solutions

```
1
+-+
>/F
+-+

2
+--+
>/\|
|//|
+-F+

2 1
+--+
>/\F
|\/|
+--+

3
+---+
>\/\|
|//\|
|\/\F
+---+

4
+----+
>/\/\|
|//\\|
|\\//|
|//\\|
+---F+
```

### Rules

- No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), as usual.
- Your program must output the solution in ASCII like what I've shown above.
- **Scoring is in bytes**, unless you have the **bonus: multiply by 0.8**.

I look forward to seeing all the a*maze*ing solutions! Ha! <sub><sup>Sorry, that was bad.</sup></sub>

Comment: Can I adopt this abandoned proposal?

Comment: @programmer5000: Yes, you may.

Answer (score 2):

## Categorical logic [on hold]

Inspired by [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/categorical-logic-some-a-are-b-all-b-are-c-therefore-all-a-are-c):

#### Task

The point of this challenge is to create a function or program that takes 3 short phrases and returns the logical assessment of the phrases.

#### Input

Each of the three phrases will be in the form: `[All|Some] [A|B|C] are [A|B|C].`, where the two `A|B|C` elements are different. The string `Therefore,{space}`, where `{space}` is a single space character, precedes the third phrase and reduces the initial capital of the third phrase to a lower case letter.

You may choose the input source and the separation of the strings. For example, `STDIN with three concatenated phrases`, `text file, phrases separated by newlines`, and `taking the phrases as command-line arguments in quotes` are all acceptable.

#### Sample input

With three concatenated phrases as example format.

- `Some tees are moos. All moos are yees. Therefore, all tees are yees.` (output: falsy)
- `All A are B. All A are C. Therefore, some B are C.` (output: ????)
- `All submissions are answers. Some submissions are winners. Therefore, some answers are winners.` (output: truthy)

#### Output

- Output for a logically correct combination of phrases must be a truthy value.
- Output for a logically incorrect combination must be a falsy value. This is also the case if the input is logically unsound e.g. `All A are B. No A are B. ...`
- Output for a logically uncertain combination must be the following string: `????`

The output may be followed by a single newline.

#### Clarifications for finicky logic

- `Some` is a subset of `All`. The following statement is badly written, but truthy: `All A are B. All A are B. Therefore, Some A are B.`
- The following statement is also truthy: `All A are B. All B are C. Therefore, some C are A`.

#### Scoring

This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

You may reduce your score by 10% if your values for `A|B|C` can contain spaces. You may assume that the value for `A|B|C` will not contain the word `{space}are{space}`).

You may reduce your score by a further 20% if your function or program also correctly handles `No` as input as well as `All|Some`.

#### Leaderboard

Standard leaderboard code goes here. Tag suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You should add what the expected output is for the sample imputs you give, so that one does not have to find if a sample is logically sound (and possibly be mistaken)

Comment: Working on a table of expected output. It's bigger than I had expected, and I haven't yet included 'No' as an option...

Comment: What is logically unsound about `All A are B. Some A are B.`? That's just equivalent to `All A are B. There is at least one A.`

Comment: @Peter Taylor, You're right. A couple of prods at the table has turned up logical differences for the same statement in different places. I don't have enough time to fix this right now, so am putting the question on hold until I can make a clear definition of required behaviour for different cases.

Comment: "*All answers are submissions. Some submissions are winners. Therefore, some answers are winners.*" This doesn't seem truthy to me. A simple substitution: *All cats are animals. Some animals are birds. Therefore, some cats are birds.*

Comment: In the few minutes at a time I'm spending on this, I'm struggling to be logically consistent. I feel that `All A are B. Therefore, all B are A` is false _because_ of the presence of `Therefore` in the statement. My gut wants me to categorise `All A are B. Therefore, all A are C` as logically uncertain, yet applying the same logic this should actually be false (as should all logically uncertain combinations). I'll have a search but would appreciate it if anyone already knows of a definitive source.

@Geobits: thank you, I've corrected that example.

Answer (score 2):

## Two mountain hikers want to meet, but must stay at the same altitude

This question is totally inspired by [this question on Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23608/hikers-meeting-in-the-middle). For ease, I have reproduced the original question here:

> Two hikers are separated by a two-dimensional mountain range, like the one shown below. The mountain range alternates between peaks and valleys, connected by straight lines.
>
> [image]
>
> Both hikers are at sea level, and the mountain range never dips below sea level.
>
> The two hikers want to meet up with each other. Prove that they can do this *while staying at the same altitude as each other for their entire journey.* They are allowed to backtrack.
>
> **Source:** http://www.cs.cmu.edu/puzzle/puzzle12.html

### Input/Output

#### Meta: what input/output format would be better?

**Continuous:**

- Input: a list of ordered pairs `(x,y)` that represent the peaks and valleys.
- Output: a sequence of positions where one hiker or both changes direction, formatted like so:

```
(x1 y1) (u1 v1)
(x2 y2) (u2 v2)
(x3 y3) (u3 v3)
...
```

**Discrete:**

- Input: a sequence of heights that represent the height of the terrain (with no flat portions). (I.e., `0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 6 5 4 3 2 3 2 1 0`, maybe with steps larger than 1?)
- Output: the left/right moves each hiker has to make, outputted like

```
L R
L L
L L
R L
...
```

### Scoring

- Scoring is in bytes.
- **Bonus:** -5% if your program produces optimal solutions.

#### Meta:

- I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicate, but still, is it?
- I'd like a better title. Would "Mountain Hikers" be good enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: Is the input sorted? Also, I don't understand the first output format.

Comment: @feersum: Sorted in the x-direction, yes. The rationale behind the first output format is that as the hikers are moving, they're both moving in one direction (not necessarily together). However, when one reaches a peak or valley, the other will stop and change direction. The output should have the positions of the hikers at these moments.

Comment: I think that allowing the input to have deltas of more than 1 would potentially require the hikers to make fractional steps, which would certainly complicate the spec. I don't think the bonus has any point: if you look at the many many existing questions about reachability in a graph (which is what this is), I think you'll find that most of the answers do breadth-first search and thus produce optimal solutions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Yeah, I realized last night that delta > 1 is a problem in the discrete case (if I want hikers to always be at integer steps). You're probably right about the bonus being pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

## Bridge Flowers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

*One of the example inputs for this challenge is a really minor puzzle in Undertale, and the example output is the solution. You have been warned.*

In the Underground, there is a mysterious plant known as the Bridge Flower. They always come in groups of four Bridge Seeds, and have some interesting properties:

- When dropped in water, a Bridge Seed floats away from you in the direction you were facing when you dropped it. It floats until it hits a wall or another Bridge Seed, at which point it stops moving.
- If four Bridge Seeds are touching, forming a straight line, and none of them are moving, they will bloom into Bridge Flowers. Bridge Flowers can support a monster's weight (or a human, but when will that ever happen?), hence the name.
- Another mysterious plant, the Bell Blossom, has a special interaction with Bridge Flowers. The Bell Blossom can be rung to turn all Bridge Flowers back into Bridge Seeds and return them to their original spot.

Consider this map, where `.` is ground,  is water, and `X` is a Bridge Seed. You'll always be on the part of the map where the Bridge Seeds are. The gap is only four tiles wide, so it's quite easy to make a bridge of Bridge Flowers.

```
........    ........  |  ........    ........
..X.....    ........  |  ........    ........
.X.X....    ........  |  ........XXXX........
..X.....    ........  |  ........    ........
........    ........  |  ........    ........
```

Here's a slightly more difficult gap to cross. Even though the straight-line distance is longer than four tiles, you can make it across with a little bit of thought.

```
........       ........  |  ........       ........
..X.....       ........  |  ........       ........
.X.X....       ........  |  ........       ........
..X.....       ........  |  ........       ........
........       ........  |  ........       ........
..         ............  |  ..     XXXX............
..         ............  |  ..         ............
```

Here's one that's even trickier than the last two. Most of this river is three tiles wide or fewer, so you can't simply make a straight-line bridge across! Thinking outside the box, though, you'll arrive at the solution.

```
....   ............  |  .... X ............
...   .............  |  ...  X.............
....   ............  |  .... X ............
.....  ............  |  .....X ............
....   ...X.X......  |  ....   ............
....   ...X.X......  |  ....   ............
     ..............  |       ..............
       ............  |         ............
```

For this challenge, write a program or function that takes a map like the ones here and outputs the same map, but with the puzzle solved (the Bridge Seeds moved to the final position of the Bridge Flowers). If there's more than one possible answer, any of them will do. You may assume there will be exactly two areas of land separated by water, with the one that you start on denoted by the presence of exactly four Bridge Seeds.

If the program can't find an answer... well, just because it's impossible doesn't mean you should give up! Don't lose your Determination! Output `Ding` to sound the Bell Blossom, reset the Bridge Seeds and try again!

Comment: It took me quite a while to understand the examples. At the very least I think you need to explain that you can pick up bridge seeds from the ground, and clarify "*floats until it hits a wall or another Bridge Seed*" to define *hits*. (I think it must include being adjacent to in directions perpendicular to the direction in which it's floating - or am I missing something?) It might also be worth stating explicitly that you don't have to drop them all from the same point.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/smallest-unicode-box-drawing) in the Puzzling SE.  Not 100% sure on the scoring, and this is my first time posting a PPCG challenge, so I'd appreciate any suggestions on improving it.

---

## Unicode Box Drawing

Write a program which outputs a diagram using all of the standard Unicode box drawing characters:

```
─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘ ├ ┤ ┬ ┴ ┼
═ ║ ╔ ╗ ╚ ╝ ╠ ╣ ╦ ╩ ╬
    ╒ ╕ ╘ ╛ ╞ ╡ ╤ ╧ ╪
    ╓ ╖ ╙ ╜ ╟ ╢ ╥ ╨ ╫
```

The diagram should have no loose ends, so:

```
┌┐ <-Allowed  ┌┐ <-Not allowed  ┌┐┌┐ <-Allowed
└┘            └┴                └┴┴┘
```

Also, single lines should line up with other single lines, and double with double:

```
├─, ╟─, ╠═, ╞═ <-Allowed  ├═, ╟═, ╠─, ╞─ <-Not allowed
```

The diagram must use each of the 40 characters at least once, and must form one contiguous, connected shape.  Because the characters might look different depending on your browser font, do not consider the space between double lines to be an actual separation.  Separations can only be between two characters.  In other words:

```
┌╖ <-Allowed  ┌┐┌┐ <-Not allowed
└╜            └┘└┘
```

Your code must compute the diagram from scratch.  You may not create an already existing diagram and just print it out.  A bonus of 20% will be awarded if your program outputs a different valid diagram based on a random seed.  (This seed may be provided as input, or you may use system time, read the seed from a file, or any other means you choose.)  Note that a random seed may be provided externally, but the diagram itself may not.  If you implement this bonus, please provide multiple examples showing different output.

This is code-golf, so scoring will be based on the number of bytes in the source code.  In addition, the length of the output will also be counted.  You get 40 characters free to account for the required characters.  Any additional characters will come at a 10% penalty.  This includes spaces/tabs, and any duplicate graph pieces.  Newlines are free (to be fair to the differences between OSs).

If your program produces multiple outputs of different lengths (due to randomness), you may use the shortest output produced, but you must provide a seed that results in that output so it can be verified.  Since this might be difficult if you used system time as a seed, entries using system time must somehow prove that they are capable of producing the smallest claimed output.  (For instance, if they produce the same length output every time, or produce the minimum claimed output at least 50% of the time.)

So in summary:

- Take length of source code in bytes.
- Add 10% for each whitespace character (not counting newlines) or duplicated character in the output.
- Subtract 20% if you implement the random seed input.

Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: "You may not create an already existing diagram and just print it out." This is probably too fuzzy. There many shades of hardcoding. Starting from including the string plainly in the code, over decoding a Base64-string which magically happens to give the correct result, all the way to "cleverly" pruning the possible diagrams your code tries to find, because you know there is a valid one in the search space. You can work around all of that by requiring programs to take some input: e.g. the actual set of characters that need to be accounted for.

Comment: Additionally, this might make an interesting code challenge instead of code golf.

Comment: You should probably also define contiguous, because some of the answers on the Puzzling.SE question have shapes which don't *look* contiguous (but are considered contiguous) because they have gaps inside the double-line characters (e.g. the "separate" box in the top left corner in the second example of the accepted answer).

Comment: @MartinBüttner This problem is caused by different rendering of the unicode characters. Here is how it looks in the SE Android app: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PlQWI.jpg

Comment: @Sleafar Oh, interesting. Might be worth mentioning anyway if some fonts display it differently.

Comment: Yeah, most fonts I've seen they look like they do in Sleafar's image.  For whatever reason, the one used on SE does not.  I think it would probably be much harder if you considered those double lines to be actual separations.  As for the hardcoding, I didn't want this to be just another "Print out <blah>" challenge, there's tons of those.  It's much more interesting if you have to derive such a graph in code.  (Which is why I added the bonus for using a random seed, because then you KNOW it's being generated on the fly.)

Comment: To avoid the hardcoding issue, I'd suggest generalizing the puzzle in some way, perhaps by giving a multiset of components to use.

Comment: Problem with using a multiset of input is you'd now have to validate said input to make sure that it's even possible to create a graph with no loose ends using the given inputs.  I think the idea of using an input parameter which is just a random seed should be sufficient to ensure the results were not hard-coded in some way.  Also, there's nothing stopping you from hard-coding it and printing the same thing every time, you just won't be eligible for the 20% bonus that way.  (Is 20% enough?  I feel like generating a valid graph is orders of magnitude more difficult than just printing one...)

Comment: You could take the multiset as input and require that _at least_ the characters in it have to be used, possibly others. The scoring could combine source code size and output size for a set of test cases.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using preset test-cases except as examples.  For one, it makes it possible to hardcode valid graphs for just the test-cases, which is contrary to the spirit of the challenge.  Also it limits the challenge to a few already-solved cases instead of making it more general.  As Sleafar found in his answer in puzzling, there are many perfect solutions for a given set, and I wouldn't want everyone to just use the same algorithm and thus produce the same graph.  I could see providing some examples, but I don't want to use *only* the example input for scoring purposes.

Answer (score 2):

## Find pattern in pixel carpet

[insert story why this needs to be as short as possible]

Given an image the goal is finding the biggest* connected* pattern of pixels, that occurs more than once. If there is more than one distinct pattern of maximum size, find the one that occurs more.

The output should consist of mask (bw image) of the size of the input, that is black where the copies of the pattern were on the original image, and white otherwise.

## * Specs

- *Biggest* as in number of pixels
- *connected* means four connected

Two instances of the pattern must not overlap.

## Example

[image]

[image]

## Meta

- consider rotations / mirroring of the patter too, or only translations?
- runntime requirement?

Comment: "You are a carpet salesman who is looking for stains in a carpet to maintain your reputation. However, since you are locally known as the 'guy who sells dirty carpets', you don't have the money to buy new hardware, and you only have a tiny hard drive and a terrible camera to try to find them with. Therefore, you're going to need a really small program in order to try to find these stains."

Comment: @VoteToClose Then it must be runnable in embedded system? A Raspberry Pi, maybe.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan Let's say it is an arduino=)

Answer (score 2):

### Optional parentheses

In text, parentheses can denote optional asides. These (often intrusive) additions can be read or skipped over, either option giving a valid sentence. Given a string with parentheses, possibly nested, output all possible readings where each parenthesized section may be omitted.

```
The(( quick)( brown)) fox jumps( over the( lazy) dog).

The fox jumps.
The quick fox jumps.
The brown fox jumps.
The quick brown fox jumps.
The fox jumps over the dog.
The quick fox jumps over the dog.
The brown fox jumps over the dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the dog.
The fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

The outputs can be in any order, but must be distinct. Note the case of `(( quick)( brown))`, where omitting both `quick` and `brown` is redundant with omitting the whole expression. But, the input won't contain any parens that enclose the empty string or are redundant with another pair of pairs.

**You may not use regular expressions.**

The input string will consist of only letters, spaces, punctuation `.,`, and parens `()`. The parens will be properly matched.

Comment: So the example is an invalid input?

Comment: @feersum It's valid, but in trying to clarify the redundancy condition, I realized it's unclear what `( quick)( brown)( quick brown)` should give. Hmm.

Comment: "You may not use regular expressions." T_T

Comment: @MartinBüttner Would it make you happier if I made reg-exp and non-reg-exp two separate "leagues"?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I wonder if it's a bit of a duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64007/8478). *If* I was allowed to use a regex approach, my answer would be almost the same (instead of repeatedly moving the contents of the parentheses to a new line, I'd duplicate the line and remove the parentheses from one of the copies, and the parentheses together with their contents from the other; followed by duplicate removal).

Comment: (Also note that even Retina can't beat a non-regex approach in Pyth on that challenge, so I doubt it'll be much different here.)

Answer (score 2):

### Compete with awk

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

The goal of this challenge is to see if the assertion often see in [awk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) question on SO is true:

> This would be faster in `whatever`

## Test Input

A 10 million lines file generated by this script line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10000000;i++) print (i%5?"miss":"hit"),i,"  third\t \tfourth"}' > file
```

Head of it:

```
$ head -10 file
miss 1   third          fourth
miss 2   third          fourth
miss 3   third          fourth
miss 4   third          fourth
hit 5   third           fourth
miss 6   third          fourth
miss 7   third          fourth
miss 8   third          fourth
miss 9   third          fourth
hit 10   third          fourth
```

## Goal:

The main goal is to compete with `awk`, to benchmark it will be on this challenge description:

- Split each line on any number of spaces (regex `[ ]+`)
- If the line start by `hit X` with X being an even number

  - print fields: 4th 1st and 3rd (in this order)

Example output (first 5 lines):

```
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
```

Restrictions:

The idea being to compete with awk, your program must behave on the same way:

- The file must be read.
- The match and output order must be modifiable as an awk program can be (Needing a simple code update is OK, it has not to be a command line parameter).
- The number of line in input file should be considered unknown.
- As long as your output can be piped to awk, the submission is valid.

## Validation:

Pipe the output of your program to

```
awk '!seen[$0]++{unq++;r=$0} END{print ((unq==1) && (seen[r]==1000000) && (r=="fourth hit third")) ? "PASS" : "FAIL"}'
```

If it show PAST, you're in :)

## Winner

The fastest code would win, to bench yourself here is a `mawk` version really competitive (which won't count toward answers as I think it's pretty hard to beat):

```
awk '/^hit +[0-9]*[02468] / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file
```

I've build a test suite on github [here](https://github.com/Tensibai/benchmark-awk-vs) which build a result table [here](http://tensibai.github.io/benchmark-awk-vs/).

Answers will be integrated within it to bench all answer on the same machine, if there's a specific way to launch your program, make it appear in the answer so I don't penalize your answer by the way it is launched.

#### Side challenge:

If you wish to save me time and craft a pull request to include your code in the test system, you're welcome.

Comment: 1. "*Split each line on spaces*" would IMO split the line `miss 1   third          fourth` into 15 fields. A possible rewording might be "*split each line around the regex `[ ]+`*" (where the otherwise unnecessary `[]` prevent MarkDown from trimming the space). 2. The question as worded is a bit too special-cased, as is the awk code you provide. If it's permissible to optimise the regex to `/hit [0-9]*0/` because you know a priori the form of the input, why would it not be permissible to optimise further and write `print "fourth hit third\n"*1E6`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the feeback, I reworded a little to be more specific on restrictions and avoid too much test input optimizations.

Comment: I still think your reference answer is cheating with `/hit [0-9]*0 /`. To match the challenge description it should use `/^hit +[0-9]*[02468] /`

Comment: @Peter ok, it does no difference in timing at end anyway (at least nothing I've been able to see on slow machines when benchmarking the codes present on GH)

Answer (score 2):

## Count up by factor keys

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

TODO: Better title

#### Information

Let the *factor key* of a number *n* be the result of the following process:

- Compute the prime factorization of *n*: n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup>  * p<sub>2</sub><sup>e<sub>2</sub></sup> * p<sub>3</sub><sup>e<sub>3</sub></sup> * ... where all p<sub>i</sub> are prime, distinct and in increasing order, and all e<sub>i</sub> are positive integers.
- Compute each p<sub>i</sub><sup>e<sub>i</sub></sup>; call these factors the f<sub>i</sub>. So n = f<sub>1</sub> * f<sub>2</sub> * f<sub>3</sub> *....
- Convert each f<sub>i</sub> to a string.
- Concatenate all the strings together.
- Evaluate as a number.

Examples:

The factor key of `2376` is `82711`, since 2376 = 2<sup>3</sup> * 3<sup>3</sup> * 11 = `8` * `27` * `11`.

The factor key of `931` is `4919`, since `931` = 7<sup>2</sup> * 19 = `49` * `19`.

As a special case, the factor key of `1` is `0`.

#### Challenge

Output all positive integers, starting from 1, in increasing orders of their factor keys. If two numbers have the same factor key, output the smaller number first. The output must be separated by a delimiter, but this delimiter can be any non-numeric character. If you choose spaces, your output should start with the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 11 13 16 17 19 6 23 10 25 14 27 29 31 37 41 12 43 28 47 36
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: In the case (I'm not sure whether it occurs, but you haven't stated that it doesn't) that two numbers have the same factor key, can they be output in any order or do you want to define a tie-break?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It does occur (see 36 and 49), but the question states "If two numbers have the same factor key, output the smaller number first."

Comment: By reverse engineering, it seems that the `e_i` must be non-zero. That's worth stating in the spec, and backing up with an example (i.e. any odd number greater than 1).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Done.

Answer (score 2):

**This is currently WIP, but please post feedback if you have any!**

---

## Best General-Purpose Compression

#### Abstract

<sup>*This paragraph is meant to summarize, the binding rules are below.*</sup>
Your task is to implement the best general purpose compression algorithm in the context of this challenge. You will be given a file corpus which contains a mix of different file types. The goal is to beat an existing answer in terms of overall size. The size is determined by the size of the compiled compression program (*and* decompression program if they are two different programs) plus the compressed size of the corpus. Your algorithm must beat standard 7z with default settings by at least 10 bytes, or if there is an existing answer, this answer by 10 bytes.

#### Corpus

This paragraph lists all files that are part of the input to your program, their size and the baseline 7z score in `7z 9.38 beta`. Licenses are linked where needed. Disclaimer: There is no political or humorous motivation behind the choices. All files were chosen because of their representation of certain formats or unique compression behavior.

**Natural Language**

**#1** - ASCII - Bibliography of Computer Security Articles 1983-88: [Download](http://textfiles.com/law/articles.law)<sup>Save-As</sup>

```
Uncompressed:      146 119
7z 9.38 beta:       17 142
File name:    articles.law
```

**#2** - ASCII - Pre-Flight Launch Preparation for the Space Shuttle: [Download](http://textfiles.com/science/fli-laun.txt)<sup>Save-As</sup>

```
Uncompressed:        44 515
7z 9.38 beta:        15 304
File name:    6_2_4_4_2.TXT
```

**#3** - ASCII - 1984 News report archive about the [Bundespost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Bundespost) Hack: [Download](http://textfiles.com/news/boh-20f8.txt)<sup>Save-As</sup> (transcribed by [Chaos Computer Club](https://www.ccc.de/en/), cites full-text articles from [Die ZEIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Zeit), [taz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Tageszeitung) et al.)

```
Uncompressed:      102 242
7z 9.38 beta:       32 382
File name:    boh-20f8.txt
```

**#4** - ASCII - (Unofficial historical transcript of) *His Last Bow* by Arthur Conan Doyle: [Download](http://www.textfiles.com/etext/AUTHORS/DOYLE/doyle-his-382.txt)<sup>Save-As</sup> (lic. Public Domain)

```
Uncompressed:           330 042
7z 9.38 beta:           110 481
File name:    doyle-his-382.txt
```

**#5** - UTF8 - Transcript of the [Rosetta Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) translated to English: [Download](https://gist.github.com/minxomat/ad67197ae2c5de29fe33)<sup>RAW->Save-As</sup> (lic./© The Nile, Notes for Travelers in Egypt, by E. A. Wallis Budge, 9th Edition, London, Thos. Cook and Son, [1905], pp. 199-211)

```
Uncompressed:                  18 270
7z 9.38 beta:                   6 299
File name:    Rosetta_EN_UTF8+BOM.txt
```

**Source Code (+ Markdown)**

**#1** - C - CPU control code taken from the linux kernel: [Download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/minxomat/bda6c660ab66aeced21f/raw/cab25fb3537a2292d53b35694bd48d0976933581/cpu.c)<sup>RAW->Save-As</sup> (lic. GPL, Rusty Russell)

```
Uncompressed: 18 866
7z 9.38 beta:  5 683
File name:     cpu.c
```

**#2** - QBASIC - COMBAT ARENA (Game): [Download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/minxomat/e0dfab0d75bf8dbd8c7a/raw/5beae77f383dadaf86c7e080214d843d3ca3bfe9/COMBAT.BAS)<sup>RAW->Save-As</sup> (© Jeff Copperthite)

```
Uncompressed: 59 792
7z 9.38 beta: 11 921
File name: COMBAT.BAS
```

**#3** - XML - The 9/11 Wikimedia dump: [Download](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/sep11wiki/20071116/sep11wiki-20071116-pages-meta-history.xml.7z) (lic. [GFDL](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights), [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/))

```
Uncompressed:                                40 557 621
7z 9.38 beta:                                   578 993
File name:    sep11wiki-20071116-pages-meta-history.xml
```

**#4** - C# - Source of the .NET Framework System.Array (CLR): [Download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/minxomat/55159aff210bcffd1387/raw/0f8e58946ebce46c560ee41f7f1c7a413f09c195/Array.cs)<sup>RAW->Save-As</sup> (lic. [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT))

```
Uncompressed:  133 646
7z 9.38 beta:   15 172
File name:    Array.cs
```

**#5** - JavaScript - jQuery 1.11.3: [Download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/minxomat/2c5d1ab2044d4ac8fb1f/raw/8cac85ea5724876213b0b0573b3bc9267adb958b/jquery-1.11.3.js)<sup>RAW->Save-As</sup> (lic. [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT))

```
Uncompressed:          284 394
7z 9.38 beta:           73 585
File name:    jquery-1.11.3.js
```

**Binary Media**

**#1** - JPG - "Flower in the Garden": [Download](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3821/19952369211_a69f6cfcb4_o_d.jpg) (lic. [CC-BY-NC-ND 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/) & © [wellenkern](https://www.flickr.com/photos/129666686@N02/))

```
Uncompressed: 10 482 521
7z 9.38 beta: 10 434 631
File name:    flower.jpg
```

**#2** - MP3 - "Mariam's Cake" by Robin Grey: [Download](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Robin_Grey/The_Nearest_Door/01_Mariams_Cake_17) (lic. [CC-BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/))

```
Uncompressed: 8 468 990
7z 9.38 beta: 8 162 146
File name:     cake.mp3
```

**#3** - Bitmap24 - DP1M7218 16:9 COLOR: [Download](http://workupload.com/file/253Rq6mR) (lic. [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) & © [iKobe!](https://www.flickr.com/photos/77110866@N05/))

```
Uncompressed: 37 834 326
7z 9.38 beta: 14 652 746
File name:    street.bmp
```

**#4** - MP4 - "Home 5x5": [Download](http://workupload.com/file/U3ZAVean) (lic. [CC-BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) & © [Michael Jones](https://vimeo.com/mikedjones))

```
Uncompressed: 6 173 898
7z 9.38 beta: 6 013 047
File name:     home.mp4
```

**#5** - binary - Block of cryptographically secure random data, a.k.a. "The Incompressible File": [Download](http://workupload.com/file/Qmn65VkJ)

```
Uncompressed: 100 000
7z 9.38 beta: 100 129
File name:    rnd.bin
```

#### Rules

**(De/)Compression Program and Algorithm**

1. The program used to compress and decompress a file is the compiled executable (or executable script).
2. You may use two or more programs and ship additional files if needed, however only one program per step (a step is de- or compression) is executed.
3. No program or part of a program is allowed to request resources that are not included in your distribution. Exceptions are standard system resources (clean install, i.e. a Java runtime would not be available when you use Windows).
4. You may use linux-, windows- or architecture-specific code.
5. You must not modify files or file names. The file names listed above are binding. Note: Some downloads may not carry the file name, you have to rename them (case-sensitive). The file names of compressed files do not matter. However, the original file names must be restored after decompression.
6. You can use any existing or new algorithm. Content mixing is of course allowed, however, you may not call any compression routines available on your system (or language). You program must be a self-contained implementation.
7. Your algorithm must not specifically target this corpus, it has to be general purpose. You are however allowed to target the used file types (e.g. by identifying the type via "Magic Bytes" and adjusting the algorithm accordingly).
8. The (de)compression program only accepts one argument, a file name. Piping program output somewhere or providing anything else is forbidden. (I.e. you'll have to write the output file yourself).

**Running your entry**

Your compression program is called 15 times, once for every file in the corpus:

```
comp articles.law
comp ...
```

This process must produce 15 compressed files on disk in the same directory (original files can be overwritten). (comp is just an example name, you don't have to use this name)

Decompression is similar. Your decompression program (which may be the same executable) is called 15 times, once for every file in the corpus:

```
decomp ...
```

Where `...` is the file name of the compressed file. This will produce the original 15 files on disk (with their original file names) (compare the SHA256 when in doubt).

Neither the compression or decompression program may take any additional command line parameters.

**Scoring**

Your score is `P+C`, where

- `P` is the size of all programs used in your distribution
- `C` is 15 files, the compressed corpus

in bytes.

Your answer must include the following:

- The source code for all parts of `P`. (**Is not counted in the score**).
- A link to a GitHub repository containing both `P` and `C`. Means you actually have to run your solution and include all compressed files. If your repository features additional files that should not be included in your score (gitignore, README etc.), put the scored files in a separate folder.

To beat someones score, your score has to beat it by at least 10 bytes. If some answer has the score `X`, then your answer has to have a score of `N <= X-10`, where `N` is your score. The starting score is set by 7z.

**Invalid Answers**

Please refrain from posting invalid answers, such as:

- Answers without source code for `P`,
- answers without compressed files, or where compressed files run against `P` produce anything but the original corpus,
- answers that contain only partial solutions.

For clarity, here's how an answer might look like:

```
I did this algorithm X. This code is used for compression:

<comp.c>

and this for decompression:

<decomp.c>

I used windows, my score therefore is 9001:

comp.exe:          234 bytes
decomp.exe:        124 bytes
Compressed files: 8643 bytes

You can download the programs and compressed files from my
repository here: github.com/foobar42.
```

### Leaderbaord and History

**Current score**: 423,424 (P) + 40,229,661 (C) = **40,662,085**
Set by: 7z 9.38 beta (Win32) on 2015-12-18

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

Comment: I love this, even if it's above my skill level. I hope it gets posted!

Comment: 1. "*The file names listed above are binding*" for what? My best guess is that the compressor has to store the original filename in the file, and the decompressor has to output to that name, but I didn't notice that that was stated explicitly anywhere. 2. `comp articles.law`: are we required to use command-line arguments and to pick an output filename ourselves, or could we use stdio and invoke as `comp <articles.law >articles.law.myz`? 3. "*Your answer must include ... A standard ZIP file*". How?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. It is irrelevant how the file name is stored, however it must be restored after decompression. I'll add that. 2. The compressed filename is not specified in the rules so it can be anything. According to the current rules `comp <articles.law >articles.law.myz` would be invalid. The only calid way to call one step is `program file`, files must be created by the step program. I'll add that. 3. I'm thinking of changing this part to "GitHub Repository". Suggestions?

Comment: I would posit that there is no such thing as truly *"General-Purpose Compression"*, at least in an information-theory sense.  Text (and various other formats) compress nicely because they are not general.  But compression of random data will not give any gain in the long run.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma GP in terms of compression algorithm means that the algorithm does not specifically target the specific files in a test suite. ZIP for example is a GP algorithm, as most other algorithms.

Comment: Rather than using GitHub repos, I think the best approach is to require all answers to be deterministic and then the scores can be verified by just running them.

Answer (score 2):

## Add two numbers (or Arithmetic on continued fraction expansions)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Given two continued fraction expansions `N,M` as lists of integers (in any suitable (human readable) format for your language) and an operation `@` (addition, substraction, multiplication and division) `+-*` or `/` (e.g. encoded as numbers 1-4 or as characters or whathever is suitable for your language) return `N@M` (the sum/difference/product/ratio) again in the form of a continued fraction expansion.

By continued fraction expansion I mean a *simple continued fraction expansion* which are of the form:

```
                   1
 a0 + -----------------------
                     1
       a1 + ------------------
                       1
             a2 + ------------
                         1
                   a3 + ------
                          ...
```

Which will be represented as a list of the form `[a0,a1,a2,a3,...]`

## Meta

Is this too complicated? Should the challenge be reduced to only one operation e.g. `+` or `*`?

Comment: It's not very complicated, and handling the four functions isn't much harder than handling just one; but if you assume that the input is two finite lists then it's possible to do a boring approach of evaluating them as reduced rationals, doing the operation, and converting back. IMO it would be more interesting to restrict to languages which support either functions with state or infinite lazy lists and to include some test cases which work with "nice" irrationals like `sqrt 2` and `e` evaluated to a given number of terms.

Comment: Would that be equivalent to letting the program take two lists of sufficient* length and a number `n`, and requiring it to return the first `n` terms? *sufficiently long such that the first `n` terms can correctly be evaluated.

Comment: I don't see how that would avoid the approach of converting to rationals, performing the operation, and converting back.

Comment: I am just trying to understand what you meant in the first comment=) You obviously can only output a finite number of terms, but this also implies that you only need a finitely many input terms. So I do not see why you would have to use 'infitine' lists as input, if you can only output finite lists. And for not excluding too many languages, my suggestion was passing another argument `n` that determines how many terms the output should consist of.

Comment: It's the difference between "You only need these `a` terms" and "You need `a` terms, but it's up to you to work out what `a` is". Working out how many terms you need is the interesting part; converting between a finite continued fraction and a rational expressed as numerator and denominator is comparatively boring.

Comment: Now I see what you mean, thank you for elaborating! I like your suggestion, I'm going to try to come up with some suitable test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## Number of cells used in optimal BF representation of a constant

[Relevant](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants).

Your task is deceptively simple. Given a number `n` (or a character `C` with char code value `n` in your encoding), output the number of cells utilized in the optimal representation of that number `n` in a standard Brainf*** interpreter with `0` <= `n` <= `255`. (8-bit wrapping.)

### Examples

```
> input
< output

> 4
< 1   ; ++++

> 0
< 1   ; empty program

> 201
< 4   ; >+[-->-[-<]>]>+

> 190
< 5   ; ++[-->-[<]>-]>

> 185
< 2   ; -[>-<-------]>++

> 255
< 1   ; -

> 242
< 1   ; --------------

> 241
< 2   ; ---[>-----<+]>
```

---

## Meta

Does more describing need to be done? <s>Should I just remove the bonuses?</s> Bonuses removed.

Comment: "*Optimal*" in what sense? And surely `0` needs one cell, to store the output?

Comment: I too think that this needs clarification. In the chat you said *optimal representation = the shortest brainfuck program outputting this number*. But I think there still might be some ambiguity, as *the shortest* might not be unique, and therefore might not have an unique number of used cells.

Comment: @flaws that is true. Minimal output length, minimizing the number of cells used.

Comment: @PeterTaylor optimal as in shortest. Will add that at home. And I'm referring to the number of cells required to modify another cell. Perhaps I'm wrong in my reasoning.

Comment: However you count the cells, `0` should surely return the same value as `4`, because neither of them use `<>`.

Comment: I vote for "remove bonuses"

Comment: @quintopia  Agreed, in retrospect they are a bad idea.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Indeed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That is true.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of this challenge is "deceptively simple". ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Polyphonic Pitch Detection

**Tags:** [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

#### Sandbox Notes

- Still in progress. I haven't made any of the test cases or snippets yet.
- I'm not sure what to tag this as. It doesn't quite fit the definition of any existing tags. [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) maybe?
- I'm thinking of making a [monophonic version of this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8236/46855) as a precursor to this one, since monophonic pitch detection is *much* easier and this one may be too difficult for most to attempt. Also note that monophonic would have more of an emphasis on perfecting an algorithm, rather than getting it to work at all.

---

Take an array of samples, and output the frequencies of the waveforms found in the samples.

---

Despite how simple this may sound, it is actually quite difficult. Even though it has been researched for almost a century, a robust and versatile algorithm for polyphonic pitch detection is yet to be found. Let's look at a simple waveform as an example:

[image: 440hz Sine Wave]

<sup>(The X-axis is in 1/440ths of a second, use the *"Play Samples"* snippet below to hear what it sounds like)</sup>

This is a 440hz sine wave. In musical terms, it is middle A or A4. The next image is a 554hz sine wave (or C#5) on top of the 440hz wave:

[image: 554hz Sine Wave]

It looks exactly the same, except slightly "squashed" (and sounds a bit "higher"). It is a major 3rd above A4, which means they sound pleasant when played together, however when you look at the waveform that adding them together creates:

[image: 440hz Sine Wave + 554hz Sine Wave]

The resulting waveform appears vastly different. To further complicate matters, it changes shape depending on the time. There are other factors like [overtones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone), background noise and the fact that real-world waveforms are more complex than sine waves which also make it tricky. (But the human brain still manages to do this effortlessly!)

#### Your Task

Receive a list of samples as signed 16-bit integers at a fixed sample-rate of 44100 samples-per-second. The input waveform will contain between 1 and 5 (inclusive) simultaneous frequencies in the range of 100hz to 2000hz.

You must output a list of frequencies detected (in hertz) with up to 2 decimal places of precision.

#### Test Cases

Each test case is on it's own line. Each line begins with the name of the test case, followed by a semi-colon (`;`), then the frequencies present in the test case (accurate to 2 decimal places) separated by commas (`,`), followed by another semi-colon, then the samples separated by commas:

`Test Case Name;123.45,67.8,90.12;3,75,1234,56789,4321,-23,-408,-9266,41,0,etc...`

Each test case will be exactly 44100 samples (1 second) long.

*(link to test case file, will include synthesized waveforms, real instrument sounds, multiple instrument/waveform types, a variety of harmonies and pitches, combinations of each of these)*

#### Scoring

The score of a submission is a percentage based on how close the submission's results are to the actual frequencies of each test case. Specifically it will calculated using the formula in the snippet below (use this to calculate your score):

*(snippet for calculating score)*

#### Rules

- No built-ins that detect pitch or extract waveform frequencies are allowed.
- Helper functions that are designed to aid frequency analysis like [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) are permitted.
- You may optimise your solution for the test cases, but you cannot hard-code the results for these specific test cases.

#### Play Samples

You can hear what certain frequencies or a list of samples sounds like by pasting them into this snippet (requires a browser that supports the Web Audio API):

```js
document.write('Enter frequencies separated by commas: <input type="text" ' +'id="Frequencies" value="440,554"><br>' +'<button id="Play" onclick="togglePlay()">Play</button><br>' +'Paste the whole test case line here: <input type="text" id="Test"><br>' +'<input type="checkbox" id="Loop"> Loop?<br>' +'<button id="PlayTest" onclick="togglePlayTest()">Play</button>');var position = 0,samples = null,sampleSize = 0xffff + 1,halfSampleSize = sampleSize / 2,bufferSize = 4096,sampleRate = 44100,context = new AudioContext(),processor = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1),oscillators = null;processor.connect(context.destination);processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {var buffer = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);if(samples) {var sampleLength = samples.length,loop = Loop.checked;for(var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {position += sampleRate / context.sampleRate;if(loop) position %= sampleLength;buffer[i] = ~~samples[position | 0] / halfSampleSize;}if(position >= sampleLength) togglePlayTest();}else buffer.fill(0);};function togglePlayTest() {if(samples) {samples = null;PlayTest.textContent = "Play";}else {var parts = Test.value.split(";");if(parts.length > 1) {PlayTest.textContent = "Stop - " + parts[0] + " (" +parts[1].split(",").map(function(f) { return f + "hz"; }).join(", ") +")";samples = parts[2].split(",").map(function(n) { return +n; });position = 0;}}}function togglePlay() {if(oscillators) {oscillators.forEach(function(o) { o.stop(); });oscillators = null;Play.textContent = "Play";}else {oscillators = [];var frequencies = Frequencies.value.split(","),gain = context.createGain();gain.gain.value = 1 / (frequencies.length + 1);gain.connect(context.destination);frequencies.forEach(function(frequency) {var oscillator = context.createOscillator();oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;oscillator.connect(gain);oscillator.start();oscillators.push(oscillator);});Play.textContent = "Stop";}}
```

#### Links

- [MUSIC Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification)
- [ESPRIT Algorithm](http://www.vtvt.ece.vt.edu/research/references/uwb/ranging_mobile_location/esprit.pdf)
- [YIN Algorithm](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf) (monophonic pitch detection)

Comment: I think it is patented in some countries, but a quite successfull one is the [yin algorithm](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf). And you might want to add [tag:test-battery]

Comment: @flawr Added. Although note that while the YIN algorithm is quite successful at finding the fundamental frequency, most of the test cases will contain multiple frequencies.

Comment: Is  that desmos I see?

Comment: @Cyoce Yep. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Roll a Die

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Most of the time in PPCG, challenges that involve dice rolling normally focus on some numeric property. However all I want you to do is to actually display the die itself in an isometric 3D format.

Your program or function should accept two optional integers representing the numbers to be displayed on the top and the front of the die respectively. If no valid value for the top is given then one of the 24 possible rolls should be uniformly chosen (but it does not need to be completely random so a time-dependent result is acceptable). If no valid value for the front is given then one of the 4 valid values should be uniformly chosen.

The die to be displayed is a standard Western die. Example: when rolling a 4, if the 1 is at the front, the number to the right is a 5; to display any other number would be an error. A more complex example is also shown below; in this case, not only is the 2 the correct number to display on the right, but all three numbers must be displayed as shown, i.e. the diagonal of the number 2 must point from 1/4 to 3/6 and not 1/3 to 4/6; the diagonal of the number 3 must point from 1/5 to 2/6 and not 1/2 to 5/6; the number 6 must point from 3 to 4 and not from 2 to 5.

```
    o-------o     o-------o 
   / *   * /|    / *   * /| 
  /       /*|   / *   * / | 
 / *   * /  |  / *   * /  | 
o-------o*  | o-------o*  | 
|       | * | |     * |   | 
|       |  *o |       |  *o 
|   *   |  /  |   *   |  /  
|       |*/   |       | /   
|       |/    | *     |/    
o-------o     o-------o
```

You must draw all the sides, corners and pips preferably using the characters as shown above. Additional whitespace is permissible if you are consistent (only the pips may vary between rolls).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer will be the winner.

Reference code (Batch):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
call :%1%2 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 call :%1 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto %time:~6,1%
goto :eof
:1
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 2 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) + 2
goto 1%front%
:2
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 3 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) * 2 + 1
goto 2%front%
:3
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 4 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) + 1
goto 5%front%
:4
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 4 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) + 1
goto 5%front%
:5
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 3 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) * 2 + 1
goto 5%front%
:6
set /a front = (%time:~7,1% %% 2) * 2 + (%time:~9,1% %% 2) + 2
goto 6%front%
:12
echo     o-------o
echo    /       /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  /       /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *     ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|     * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:13
echo     o-------o
echo    /       /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  /       /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^|     * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *     ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:14
echo     o-------o
echo    /       /^|
echo   /   *   / ^|
echo  /       /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *   * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:15
echo     o-------o
echo    /       /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  /       /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *   * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:21
echo     o-------o
echo    / *     /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  /     * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^|       ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|       ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:23
echo     o-------o
echo    /     * /^|
echo   /       / ^|
echo  / *     /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *     ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^|     * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:24
echo     o-------o
echo    /     * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / *     /* ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *   * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^| */
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:26
echo     o-------o
echo    / *     /^|
echo   /       / ^|
echo  /     * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| * * * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| * * * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:31
echo     o-------o
echo    /     * /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  / *     /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^|       ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|       ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:32
echo     o-------o
echo    / *     /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  /     * /  ^|
echo o-------o* *^|
echo ^|     * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|* *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *     ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:35
echo     o-------o
echo    / *     /^|
echo   /   *   / ^|
echo  /     * /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *   * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:36
echo     o-------o
echo    /     * /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  / *     /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *   * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^| *   * ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:41
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^|       ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|       ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:42
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /       / ^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^|     * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| *     ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:45
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o* *^|
echo ^| *   * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|* *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:46
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *   * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^| *   * ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:51
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /   *   / ^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^|       ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^|       ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:53
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  / *   * /* ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *     ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^| */
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|     * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:54
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /   *   / ^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *   * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:56
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   /   *   /*^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| * * * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| * * * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:62
echo     o-------o
echo    / * * * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / * * * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *     ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^|     * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:63
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   / *   * / ^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^|     * ^|   ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^| /
echo ^| *     ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:64
echo     o-------o
echo    / *   * /^|
echo   / *   * /*^|
echo  / *   * /  ^|
echo o-------o*  ^|
echo ^| *   * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|  *o
echo ^|       ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
goto :eof
:65
echo     o-------o
echo    / * * * /^|
echo   /       /*^|
echo  / * * * /  ^|
echo o-------o   ^|
echo ^| *   * ^| * ^|
echo ^|       ^|   o
echo ^|   *   ^|  /
echo ^|       ^|*/
echo ^| *   * ^|/
echo o-------o
```

---

```
        o-------o
        | *   * |
        |       |
        |   *   |
        |       |
        | *   * |
o-------o-------o-------o-------o
| *   * |       | *     | * * * |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |   *   |   *   |       |
|       |       |       |       |
| *   * |       |     * | * * * |
o-------o-------o-------o-------o
        | *     |
        |       |
        |       |
        |       |
        |     * |
        o-------o


    o-------o
   / * * * /|
  / * * * /*|
 / * * * /* |
o-------o* *|
| * * * | * |
|       |* *o
| * * * | */
|       |*/
| * * * |/
o-------o
```

Comment: Re "real standard dice". [Both left-handed and right-handed dice exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Arrangement) (depending on culture), so it might be worth mentioning explicitly which of the two it is, instead of giving a single example. "You can earn a bonus for rolling several dice but in this case you must display the dice horizontally." You forgot to mention how much that bonus is worth [but I would recommending leaving it out completely](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/8478).

Comment: It's also sort of implied that two numbers is also valid input (provided they can be on adjacent sides), but you never state how that input is to be handled. Likewise, what if the input has more than two numbers? I'd also prefer a fixed output format instead of letting people choose their own ASCII art. It's bound to derail into arguments of how much visual complexity is sufficient to display the die properly.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Sorry I didn't know about Chinese dice, and the bad wording in some of my paragraphs; I hope this version is better.

Comment: The diagram of two dice isn't quite enough for me to visualise the all the cases, and the batch script isn't the easiest to read either because of the escaping. I think it would be an improvement to give an unfolded net, possibly a diagram showing all the possible pip positions, and if you want to have a full test suite then to rewrite it in JavaScript and make it a Stack Snippet. Since I've already gone to the effort of producing the first two diagrams to evaluate how helpful I find them, I'll edit them in as a footnote and leave you to decide whether and where you want to use them.

Answer (score 2):

## Sock Drawer Simulator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Socks are often kept in drawers, and when people wear socks they like the left and right socks to match <sup>[[citation needed]](http://example.com)</sup>.

### Challenge

Given an array of the number of socks of each color, simulate the process of drawing socks, and output the color of the first pair found. You may assume that:

- Socks are drawn sequentially, randomly and without replacement.
- A pair is found when a sock of a color that has already been drawn is drawn.

Obviously, the precise algorithm doesn't matter as long as the output probability distribution is correct.

### Input

A nonempty array of positive integers representing the frequency of each color of sock. For example, `[3,1,4,1,5]` could represent a drawer with three teal, one aquamarine, four green, one cyan, and five cerulean socks. There will always be at least one possible pair.

### Output

A nonnegative integer representing the color (index) of the sock drawn. You may consistently use either one-indexed or zero-indexed arrays.

Answer (score 2):

## Anything but stacks

[language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

---

Stack-based languages are, like totally, all the rage these days.  From GolfScript, to CJam, to MATL, it seems like stack-based languages are *popping* up everywhere.  But now, it is time to *push* forward and explore new memory models.

In this challenge, you are to create a new programming language based off of any other data structure.

---

Still undecided is the "goal" of this challenge.  The main idea is that, by using a unique data structure, these new languages may have advantages for certain types of problems.  Since different languages would use different structures, however, there's not any single set of challenges that would provide a fair comparison.  An alternative idea is to pick a single data structure and have everybody use it.

---

I'm going to work off the "use a specific data structure" idea, since that's really the only thing that can narrow the focus of this question.  So, maybe some options are...

- Queues
- Trees (except I'm not sure how a "tree without branching" would be different from a "stack")
- Priority Queues
- Sets, etc.
- Associative arrays (dicts/hashmaps)

The next step might be to find some types of problems to target.  **Are there any algorithms that are known to be exceptionally difficult to implement with a stack?**

Comment: I think a lot of people will follow Pyth (fixed-arity prefix with iteration as a backup) or Jelly (tacit) if the goal is a golfing language.

Comment: This is currently too broad by miles.

Comment: I definitely agree with Peter. "An alternative idea is to pick a single data structure and have everybody use it." That seems a like a much better idea, and then you need to make sure that that's the only type of memory that's allowed (maybe except for a finite amount, like a handful of registers). Even then, it definitely needs some sort of goal. Requiring TC-ness might also be a good idea depending on what kind of answers you're looking for.

Comment: I think set-based languages would be the most interesting, since sets can't have an order, and most other data structures can implement stacks easily. There are also so many different directions to take with them.

Comment: Somewhere far down on my list of esolang ideas are two languages using [stacked cups](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61153/8478) as a data structure (I'd like to implement a very minimalistic one that doesn't go far beyond the instructions in that challenge, and a feature-rich one, where you're actually programming two hands that can move cups). Anyway, I'd be willing to offer that idea as a data structure for your challenge.

Comment: @user1657355 [HPR](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61804/create-a-programming-language-that-only-appears-to-be-unusable/62102#62102) is set-based, although the set can contain lists.

Comment: Regular expressions. _Those_ are probably hard with a stack based language. Parsing expressions would be hard, I would think, as well.

Comment: I was thinking of two deque based languages.

Answer (score 2):

### Write Hamlet in 1024 bytes

Here is [a text file containing Shakespeare's play *Hamlet*](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~matty/Shakespeare/texts/tragedies/hamlet).

You will write a program, less than 1024 bytes in length, that outputs this text to a file, STDOUT or nearest available equivalent. Since this is clearly impossible, you don't have to output the exact text, just get as close as possible.

To measure how close your output is to the original, use the Python 3 script below. It works by concatenating the original text onto the end of your file, then compressing the result using the `lzma` algorithm, and then subtracting the compressed size of your file alone. This works because if your file contains a lot of common features with the original then the compression algorithm can take advantage of this to make a smaller file. A more sophisticated version of this idea is called [normalised compression distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_compression_distance).

All answers should contain the code, at least a brief explanation of how it works (full explanations are encouraged), and the first 2000 characters or so of its output.

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). Scores are calculated using the script below. The lowest score wins.

**Rules and clarifications**

- Your program must be completely self-contained within a single file, taking no input, loading no files, and executing no other programs. Importing libraries is permitted.
- Your program must run deterministically, producing the same output every time
- Your output must contain only printable ASCII characters, tabs and newlines. (That is, characters with codes 32 to 126 inclusive, plus 9 and 10.) The comparison script checks for this.
- Your output must be the same size as the original file, 182581 bytes.
- You may not use any built-ins or library code that provides compression or decompression algorithms. (e.g. `lzma`, `bz2` etc.) It's OK to use them if you can implement them yourself inside the character limit. Base conversion is OK, and libraries implementing data structures such as Huffman trees are OK.
- If for some reason your language or one of its libraries contains a function that outputs some or all of the text of Hamlet, you may not use that function.
- Your program must be written in a programming language, as defined in [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/21034). This definition must apply to your source code, not just to any compiler/interpreter flags used to run it.
- In the case of any inconsistency in the script's behaviour between machines, the version on my machine is the definitive one. (Python 3.4.3 on a Mac.)

Here is the comparison code to use. It requires Python 3 because of the `lzma` dependency. (`lzma` is much better than `bz2` or `gzip` for this purpose.) It requires the text file linked above to be in the same directory with the name `ORIGINAL.txt`. Run it with a command like

```
python3 compare.py my_output.txt
```

[to do: produce and supply a zip file containing this script together with ORIGINAL.txt]

```
import lzma
import sys

with open("ORIGINAL.txt", 'r') as file:
    orig = file.read()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

def csize(txt):
    return len(lzma.compress(txt.encode('utf-8')))

character_codes = {ord(c) for c in text}
valid_codes = set([9,10] + list(range(32,127)))
if character_codes - valid_codes:
    print("NOT VALID: file contains a non-printable character")
else:
    print( csize(text + orig) - csize(text) )
```

**Technical notes**

The compressed size of the original file is 64976 bytes. In an ideal world the original file would have a score of 0, but it actually scores 100. Shakespeare's *Macbeth* scores 61776, so that should probably be considered a pretty good score.

Tags: [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

Comment: One problem I see is dictionary compression should be really powerful here, but prohibitive for any languages that don't have a built-in dictionary (because including one would clearly exceed the byte limit). What about languages that do have built-in dictionaries though? (Jelly's string literals can be dictionary-compressed out of the box, and I think Mathematica can load a dictionary with a single function call, too.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I guess I personally am OK with languages with built-in dictionaries - it just seems like using the right tool for the job. But if that would be seen as unacceptably biasing the challenge toward a certain set of languages, I'm OK with putting something in to prohibit it.

Comment: I just realised that the optimal solution might consist of a 1024-character string literal. For that reason I might add a requirement that the output be the same length as the original file. (But first I have to think about whether that's really likely to be a problem.)

Comment: Does base conversion count as a "compression or decompression algorithm"? What about Huffman tree-related functions?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think I would say both are OK - I'm mostly just trying to prevent solutions that don't do much other than `bz2.decompress('[some long string]')`. If you implemented your own decompression then we learn something from the answer, even if you did it using tools designed for that purpose. However, if you have an intuition that this would devolve into something uninteresting please let me know.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added a restriction on the source character set as well, which should head off some of the most annoying consequences of those things.

Comment: I asked about base conversion because it's one of the techniques most frequently used on this site for compression, and about Huffman because it seemed like a gray area which should be mentioned explicitly. On an unrelated note, would it not be a better measure to do the concatenation the other way round, so that the "compressed" Hamlet is training the LZMA bigraph dictionary for the real one? Otherwise the best score would probably be obtained by repeating some large chunk from near the end of the real one as many times as needed to meet the target length.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've made that change. (I tested it on a few test files, including one composed of the last 5% of Hamlet repeated 20 times, and it didn't make *much* difference, but it changed the scores by 100 or so.)

Comment: (One of the reasons that LZMA is good for this purpose is that it's close to being a "normal compression algorithm", which includes being close to invariant with respect to swapping the concatenated strings around.)

Comment: I changed my mind about trying to keep the source printable. It's a nice thing to have but it means having rules that are too complex, and people will just try to loophole their way around them anyway. So that means base coding is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The free monoid on two letters 'x' and 'y' is the set of all finite strings you can make up from them, including the empty string, with their concatenation a binary operation. So the elements of this free monoid look like this: `""`, `"x"`, `"y"`, `"xy"`, `"yx"`, `"xx"`, `"yy"` and so on. Strings like `"xxxx"` are often written as powers and we don't generally use the quotes: `x^4`.

This challenge is about a certain binary relation on this free monoid. Suppose we decide to treat `x^2` abd `y^2` as "the same". Which other strings (or "words", as they're called) will have to become "the same" (or congruent under the relation `x^2 = y^2`) as a result? In `xxy`, we can substitute `yy` for `xx`, which means that `xxy` is congruent to `yyy`. But then, the last `yy` in that string can be turned into `xx` as well, so `yxx` is congruent to the previous ones as well. A nice thing about this relation is that any congruent words will have to have the same length, so the number of words congruent to a given one is always finite. (To read up on this, you can look up things like "[string rewriting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Thue_system)", "[transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)", "[congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation)".)

Take a string as input. The string is assumed to be of any length (including the empty string) and to contain at most two different characters (chosen by the user from the printable ASCII set or equivalent), say `x` and `y`. The program will interpret the string as a word in the free monoid on `x` and `y` and output all the other words of that monoid, also as strings, using the characters chosen by the user, congruent to the input word under the relation `x^2 = y^2`, in any order. Every congruent word must occur exactly once, including the input.

The words in the output have to be consistently separated by any non-empty string of printable characters not chosen by the user. If the input word contains less than two distinct characters, your program will assume the missing one(s) according to your choice, but that must not overlap with the separator. How exactly you want to take the input and output the words is up to you, but it must be possible to enter any valid string as input.

This has to be a complete program, not a function. No loopholes please.

Examples of input and output:

```
in: empty string
out: empty string

in: xx
out: xx yy

in: xy
out: xy

in: xyx
out: xyx

in: xyy
out: xyy xxx yyx

in: xxxx
out: xxxx yyxx yyyy yxxy xyyx xxyy

in: xyyxy
out: xyyxy xxxxy yyxxy yyyyy xxyyy xxyxx yyyxx yxxxx yxyyx yxxyy
```

(Note that the whitespace is a valid input character -- your program must choose a different separator if the user chooses to use it as a letter.)

Don't worry about things like the maximal length of the input or the output. The logic of your program has to work for all input word lengths, but the program only needs to work for reasonably long inputs.

Please give a short explanation of why your program works.

Comment: You might want to include some more background about monoids and congruent words. Also, test cases should include the expected output as well. The test cases would also be more readable in a code block without quotes. And I get that you want to show with the test cases that the choice of characters is arbitrary, but that's fairly clear from the spec. It would be more useful if you stuck to one set of characters in the test cases to make it easier for people to transform all of them at once into their own input format (instead of having to rewrite each one independently by hand).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I guess I'm not attached to the test cases. I got rid of them and added a short introduction.

Comment: I didn't mean you should get rid of the test cases. They're important. I just meant, use the same pair of characters throughout to make them more usable.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've added new test cases.

Comment: Why are functions banned?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy This is personal preference - it's hard for me to understand why a function should be OK. It doesn't do the job (by itself) and it seems unfair to the people who write runnable programs. I feel that they do more. I'm new here and new to code golf so I don't know. Is there a reason functions should be allowed other than to make the top answer this much shorter?

Comment: Well, in powerful golfing languages, making a function can actually be longer (eg Cjam, Golfscript) But in Java, you have to include `class Q{public static void main(String[]a){...}}` in all your programs. Even in other (normal) languages, fewer bytes for input/output could help beat a golfing language. tl;dr It helps languages like Java have a chance against Python or other less-boilerplatey languages.

Comment: Why are you demanding that the program allow its user to input a separator? What's the benefit in that as opposed to allowing the program to use whatever separator (not one of the letters, obviously) the programmer wants?

Comment: @msh210 I don't think I'm saying that. My intention was to say exactly what you're saying. The separator is chosen by the programmer/program, but it can't be one of the letters. The letters are chosen by the user from a certain set and the separator is chosen from the same set.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Allowing the user to choose any letters and forcing the program to come up with a different separator seems like it only adds arbitrary complexity that’s unrelated to the interesting part of the challenge. You should either guarantee that the valid input letters are x and y, or allow the programmer to choose the valid input letters.

Answer (score 2):

## Create an unkillable Windows process

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In various versions of the Microsoft Windows operating system, it is possible for a process to enter a state where it cannot be killed by the 'End Process' feature in the Task Manager. Your goal is to create a user-mode program that enters such a state (or spawns a process that does) using as few bytes of code as possible. Please state the version of Windows on which you have tested the program.

Some techniques for creating unkillable processes can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/create-a-unterminable-process-in-windows).

Be warned that such processes may cause a performance impact, so be prepared to reboot if necessary when testing any of these programs.

TODO:

- Minimum version? The #1 in the accepted answer seems too easy.
- #2 is also lame so maybe taskkill should be the standard instead of Task Manager.

Comment: This is coming fairly close to a challenge asking for malicious software.

Comment: @MartinBüttner It's not completely clear, but the discussion on that question seemed to indicate that a process in a zombie state could not actually execute any longer, making it useless for malware.

Answer (score 2):

## The greatest power...

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

*Yeah, I'm still trying to come up with a better title...*

A positive integer `n` is a *perfect power of order `k`* if it can be written in the form `mk` for some integer `m`. The *greatest power* of `n` is the largest number `k` for which `n` is a perfect power of order `k`. Some examples:

- `9 = 32` is a perfect square, and it cannot be written in the form `mk` for `k > 2`, so it's greatest power is `2`.
- `16 = 42` is also a perfect square. However it can also be written as `16 = 24`, so it's greatest power is `4` instead.
- `24 = 241` is not a perfect power of any order `k > 1` so it's greatest power is `1`.

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `n > 1`, determine its greatest power. This is OEIS entry [A052409](https://oeis.org/A052409) (with `a(1)` defined as `0`, but you don't need to handle that).

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

The first 100 terms of the sequence (starting from `n = 2`) are:

```
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
```

Comment: Can anyone find a similar challenge we've already done?

Comment: I thought up this exact challenge a few days ago, but didn't bother writing it out. Glad to see that someone else did :)

Comment: Power Points? :P

Comment: Also I think I found it: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/501/31625 although I would prefer to close that as a dupe of this one, I think. It has basically no spec...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hmmm, that might editable without invalidating answers though.

Comment: By the looks of it, some answers are already invalid, and a bunch give 0 for the values that, in yours, should give 1. Not sure what to do with that, I think it'd have to say that 1 or 0 was acceptable?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think even by the little bit of spec that's there, returning `0` for anything is wrong. Let's see if froddy responds to my comment. Otherwise, I'll probably go ahead with this one.

Comment: Rather than "greatest power" it's "greatest-order root". But of course that's not a catchy title :-)

Comment: @DonMuesli I think it would be the greatest root-order, because the greatest-order root should be `m`, right?

Comment: @Martin Yes, you are right. I had understood the challenge the other way around. Very nice challenge BTW! (Meaning I think I have a 10-byte answer, hehehe)

Comment: *Submit to a greater power*?

Comment: There was a similar question about expressing your number `n` in all possible ways as `n=a^b`, but I'm not finding it now.

Comment: @xnor Hmmm, let me know when you do.

Comment: @xnor There's http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/564/8478 also by froddy.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Here is is: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58047/20260

Comment: @xnor Hm can you think of any shortcuts to this challenge that don't involve trying a range of powers anyway?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Only one I can think of is to compute the prime factorization, then take the gcd of the exponents.

Comment: @xnor Oh yeah, right. That's probably also going to be the most golfable in a whole bunch of languages.

Answer (score 2):

### Generate a waveform from audio [audio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given an audio file, in any common audio format (such as MP3, OGG, WMA, M4A, or WAV) of your choice, as input, output an image, in any common image format (such as PNG, JPG, PPM, BMP, SVG, or GIF) of your choice, of a waveform representing the audio input.

Here is an example image, generated with Audacity from [this audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmCCQxVBfyM):

[image: waveform example]

For reference, here is what an amplitude 1 sine wave at 440 Hz looks like:

[image: sine 440]

And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noJAmTcufH0) is what it sounds like (warning: it doesn't sound good).

### Restrictions

- The background of the image must be white (`#FFFFFF` in HTML notation)
- The waveform may be any color that is sufficiently distinguishable from the background
- The input audio must be sampled at 44.1 kHz with 32-bit floats (in the inclusive range [-1, 1])
- For raster graphics:

  - Sample points must be plotted every 5 pixels
  - The height must be an odd number of pixels, no less than 101
- Because vector graphics can scale indefinitely, the above restrictions do not apply
- The horizontal line in the middle of the image represents 0 amplitude, and the top and bottom of the image represent 1 and -1 amplitude, respectively
- The vertical scale must be linear, not logarithmic (the amplitude of the wave, not the relative loudness)
- The color of the wave, height of the image, input format, and output format must be the same every time your submission is run (for example, you cannot output as a PNG for one input, and a JPG for another)
- For the sake of testing/verification, submissions must run in under 1 minute on my machine (Core i3-3240 quad core, 3.4 GHz, 8 GB RAM) for any input.

Comment: "common format"?

Comment: @CoolestVeto Examples for audio include MP3, WAV, WMA, M4A, and OGG (basically any format Audacity can export to). Examples for graphics include PNG, JPG, BMP, SVG, PPM, GIF, etc.

Comment: So we're permitted to use any of those formats, not that we must allow for any of those formats?

Comment: @CoolestVeto Correct.

Comment: Horizontal scale is specified, but (minimum) vertical scale is not.

Comment: @PeterTaylor What do you mean? *The horizontal center of the image should represent 0 (silence), and the top/bottom should represent ±1 (the maximum/minimum measureable sample amplitude). The vertical scale should be linear, not logarithmic (measuring amplitude of the wave, not the loudness in decibels).*

Comment: A 3-pixel high image could meet that spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, I see the issue now, thanks.

Comment: Re *The input audio must be sampled at 44.1 kHz with 32-bit floats (in the inclusive range [0, 1])*, did you maybe mean the inclusive range [-1, 1]?

Comment: @zwol I did indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Igpā Atinlā (Pig Latin)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

In this challenge, we will be translating strings of words to Pig Latin.

**Input:** A string of words (a "word" is a continuous sequence of the characters A-Za-z) (ASCII only).

**Output:** The translated version of the input. Translations described below.

**Some Definitions:**

First, the following are *vowels*: "A,a, E,e, I, i, O, o, U, u". Any alphabet character that is not a vowel is a consonant. A *consonant cluster* is any continuous sequence of consonants surrounded on both sides by non consonant characters (or beginning/end of input). An example, the clusters are in bold:

"I a**m** **tw**o **h**u**ndr**e**d** **y**ea**rs** **y**ou**ng**, **y**ou **ch**i**ld**-**m**o**th**e**r**."

A *word* is a set of alphabet characters surrounded on both sides by non-alphabet characters.

**Translation:**

1. If the string "'s" or "'d" or "'t" appears ("apostrophe s/d/t"), remove the apostrophe.

For each *word* in the string, do the following:

2. If a word only contains capital letters (A-Z), ignore the next step.
3. If the beginning of the word was a capital letter (A-Z) AND a consonant, change it to its lower-case equivalent (a-z). Then capitalize the first vowel in the word. If no vowel exists, then recapitalize the letter. e.g. ***S***tretch --> *str**E**tch*, "Twxx" --> "Twxx"
4. If the word begins with a consonant cluster, move that consonant cluster to the end of the word. e.g. ***str***etch --> *etch**str***
5. Append the "hard a" character to the word. If every letter is capital, append 'Ā'. Otherwise append 'ā' e.g. *etchstr* --> *etchstr**ā***, "ATC" --> "ATC**Ā**"

   - If your language is unable to output 'ā' and 'Ā', you may use "ay" and "AY" respectively.
6. If the word is "A" or "a", ignore previous instructions. Transform the word to "Anā" or "anā", respectively. (because in Pig Latin, everything begins with a vowel, so we use the article "an" instead of "a")

**Test Cases:** (*I think these are right*)

- "I want to be a cat." --> "IĀ antwā otā ebā anā atcā"
- "That's a really nice... ass-car?" --> "Atsthā anā eallyrā icenā... assā-arcā?"
- "[CR][NL]'ssssssssssssssssssTRUExxxxxxxxIAMSOCOOL" --> "[CRĀ][NLĀ]UExxxxxxxxIAMSOCOOLssssssssssssssssssTRā"
- "THIS CHALLENGE IS PROBABLY A DUPE" --> "ISTHĀ ALLENGECHĀ ISĀ OBABLYPRĀ Anā UPEDĀ"
- "I SAT ON an APPLE" --> "IĀ ATSĀ ONĀ anā APPLEĀ"

Comment: Is the string: `bc` a consonant cluster?

Comment: Yeah. "bc" --> "bcā". Is that not what the spec says?

Comment: ok, I wanted to clarify if the start/end of a string counts as a "non-vowel" character. Perhaps a better description is: "a sequence of consonants"?

Comment: I think it's clearer now?

Comment: [Very closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8797/31625).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think mine is sufficiently more complicated that it wouldn't be a dupe. However I don't know that the complexities are interesting enough to merit posting.

Comment: Some languages might not support the special a and A. Maybe allow regular A's?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I know that some languages can't but I think that makes the challenge more interesting. At least a bit. If people disagree, I might change it to "ay" and "AY"

Comment: In the `THIS CHALLENGE IS PROBABLY A DUPE` test case, the A should become `Anā` instead of `ANĀ`.

Comment: I'd call this a dup.

Answer (score 2):

## Diagonals of an Array

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

The ***k***-th diagonal of a two-dimensional array is a list of all elements in positions `(a,a+k)`. Your task is to output all of the diagonals.

For example, the diagonals of

```
[[3,1,4,1],[5,9,2,6],[5,3,5,8]]
```

are:

```
[[1],[4,6],[1,2,8],[3,9,5],[5,3],[5]]
```

Which can be visualized thusly:

```
k -2-1 0 1 2 3
    \ \ \ \ \ \
     \ \ 3 1 4 1
      \ \ \ \ \
       \ 5 9 2 6
        \ \ \ \
         5 3 5 8
```

#### Input

A rectangular nested array or 2D array of positive integers, which will be nonempty.

#### Output

Its diagonals in any consistent order.

#### Test cases

```
[[3,1,4,1],[5,9,2,6],[5,3,5,8]]
[[1],[4,6],[1,2,8],[3,9,5],[5,3],[5]]

[[42]]
[[42]]

[[57,72,15,66,49,01,53,28,60,60,65,12,09,00,82]]
[[57],[72],[15],[66],[49],[1],[53],[28],[60],[60],[65],[12],[9],[0],[82]]

[[57],[72],[15],[66],[49],[1],[53],[28],[60],[60],[65],[12],[9],[0],[82]]
[[57],[72],[15],[66],[49],[1],[53],[28],[60],[60],[65],[12],[9],[0],[82]]
```

---

Maybe a second question about n-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I suggest a requirement that the order of the output diagonals be consistent (the same irrespective of input); and add a row matrix and column matrix as test cases

Comment: [Now almost a duplicate.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77219/8478) Also, Jelly has a 2-character built-in for this. (Just to let you know.)

Answer (score 2):

## Maximum of Two Roman Numerals

You should write a program or function which returns the maximum of two [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

### Input

- Two positive integers between 1 and 3999 (inclusive) with their Roman numeral representation string.
- The two strings can be separated by a space or inputted in the standard list representation of your language.
- `4`, `9`, `40`, ... are written as `IV`, `IX`, `XL`, ...
- Trailing newline is optional.

### Output

- The larger Roman numeral as string.
- Trailing newline is optional.
- If the two inputs are equal you should still only return one of them.

### Examples

Format is `input => output (explanation)`

```
XXIX DI => DI (29 < 501)
V X => X    

TODO more
```

Built-in functions involving Roman numerals are prohibited.

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: Can I adopt this abandoned challenge?

Comment: @programmer5000 Yep!

Answer (score 2):

## Wargame Tank Simulation

Some of you may have heard of the Wargame series of computer based real time strategy game.  These games pit teams of players with primarily cold war era units to see how a hot cold war would have played out.  The goal of this challenge is to simulate a tank battle in these games.

**Input**

- Two "tanks" (one red and one blue) will be entered into your program or function.  Each tank is classified by a rate of fire, accuracy, armor value, and attack power value.

**Challenge**

From the inputs above, simulate the two tanks fighting.  You will do this by having each tank fire according to its rate of fire.  If it hits (randomly determined by accuracy), a tank will do damage according to the armor value of its target and its own attack power.  The formula for damage is `floor[(attackpower - armor)/2]`.  Therefore a tank with 10 attack power against a tank with 5 armor would do 2 damage.

Tank crews also have morale, which follows the following rule

- There are four possible morale values; calm, worried, scared, and panicked. Tanks always start calm.  These names do not need to be in your code, in the sample below I've used calm = 1, worried = 2, etc.
- Each morale value reduces the accuracy as follows: Calm -> 100% (no change), worried -> 75%, scared -> 50%, panicked -> 25%.   Therefore a panicked tank which normally has 60% accuracy now has 0.25 * 0.6 = 15% accuracy
- Each hit by the opposing tank degrades morale by one level, each miss upgrades the morale by one level.

For example:

```
morale: calm  |  worried  |  calm  |  worried  |  scared
hit:         hit         miss     hit         hit
```

**Rules:**

- Input should be two parameters to repesent each tank (I've used two tuples in the example below). Inputs may be provided in any order, just be sure to state which one is which. Input may be provided by user input via STDIN, read from a file, or parameters passed to a function call.
- Each tank starts with 10 health.
- Rate of fire will either be 8.5, 7.5, 6.5, 6, or 5 seconds between shots.
- Tanks start loaded, so each fires at time = 0.  Because Communists are sneaky, red fires first.
- Accuracy must be randomly rolled.
- Ineffective hits (hits which do no damage) have an effect on morale! (because it probably sounds terrifying)
- Naturally since we want to see the action, output will be an update after each shot.  The update will contain the time of the shot, whom it was made by (red or blue), health of both tanks, and the morale of both tank crews.  Output maybe be presented in any format so long as it contains all of the required information in a human readable fashion (items must be delimited in some way).  Similar to input, please describe your output format in the answer.
- Engagements are limited to 100 seconds. If you play the game you know this is because a plane has swooped in by then.  For our purposes if both tanks are alive at this point, it is a draw.
- After one tank reaches 0 health (or after 100 seconds), print which tank is victorious (`"Red"` or `"Blue"`) or `"Draw"` if appropriate.  I don't care about  trailing whitespace or newlines.
- Printint output may be printing to STDOUT or writing to a file
- Shortest answer in bytes wins

**[Sample Python Implementation](https://ideone.com/tTu4uv)**

```
import random, math

def Shot_Result(acc, morale, power, armor):
    Morale = {1: 1., 2: 0.75, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.25}
    actual_acc = acc * Morale[morale]
    roll = random.random()
    if roll < actual_acc:
        dmg = max(0,math.floor((power-armor)/2))
    else:
        dmg = -1
        
    return dmg
    
    
def main(Red, Blue):
    red_rate, red_acc, red_armor, red_pow = Red
    blue_rate, blue_acc, blue_armor, blue_pow = Blue
    
    red_health = blue_health = 10
    red_morale = blue_morale = 1
    
    red_shots = [("Red", shot/100.) for shot in range(0,10000,int(red_rate*100))]
    blue_shots = [("Blue", shot/100.) for shot in range(0,10000,int(blue_rate*100))]
    
    Shots = sorted(red_shots + blue_shots, key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    print "{:^6}|{:^6}|{:^12}|{:^12}|{:^12}|{:^12}|".format("Shot","Time","Red Health","Blue Health","Red Morale","Blue Morale")
    
    for shot in Shots:
        if shot[0] == "Red":
            dmg = Shot_Result(red_acc, red_morale, red_pow, blue_armor)
            if dmg >= 0:
                blue_health -= dmg
                blue_morale = min(blue_morale+1,4)
            else:
                blue_morale = max(blue_morale-1,1)
        else:
            dmg = Shot_Result(blue_acc, blue_morale, blue_pow, red_armor)
            if dmg >= 0:
                red_health -= dmg
                red_morale = min(red_morale+1,4)
            else:
                red_morale = max(red_morale-1,1)
                
        print "{:^6}|{:^6}|{:^12}|{:^12}|{:^12}|{:^12}|".format(shot[0], shot[1], red_health, blue_health, red_morale, blue_morale)
        
        if red_health <= 0:
            print "Blue tank is victorious!"
            break
        if blue_health <= 0:
            print "Red tank is victorious!"
            break
    else:        
        print "It's a draw!"
```

**Sample Output** (Yours does not need to be this fancy)

```
 Shot | Time | Red Health |Blue Health | Red Morale |Blue Morale |
 Red  | 0.0  |     10     |    5.0     |     1      |     2      |
 Blue | 0.0  |     10     |    5.0     |     1      |     2      |
 Blue | 6.5  |     10     |    5.0     |     1      |     2      |
 Red  | 8.5  |     10     |    5.0     |     1      |     1      |
 Blue | 13.0 |    5.0     |    5.0     |     2      |     1      |
 Red  | 17.0 |    5.0     |    5.0     |     2      |     1      |
 Blue | 19.5 |    5.0     |    5.0     |     1      |     1      |
 Red  | 25.5 |    5.0     |    5.0     |     1      |     1      |
 Blue | 26.0 |    0.0     |    5.0     |     2      |     1      |
Blue tank is victorious!
```

Comment: Its a good challenge, but you need to define your input/outputs a little more.  I'd recommend indicating that tanks are passed in as a tuple/list, which tank is passed in first, and then define what the functions should return if red wins/blue wins/tie.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, I've made some slight updates to the rules.  I want to keep things open as I often find myself frustrated with arbitrary I/O restrictions.

Comment: Flexible I/O is the way to go :)  Looks good from my end.

Answer (score 2):

## Help! Everything is in Wingdings!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Your task is to write a program or function that converts wingdings to a readable font. 
The input to the program will be the path to a png file with between 1 and 10 wingdings characters. Your output should be the message contained in the wingdings characters.

### Specifications

Each test case will be a screenshot of the message as rendered in Microsoft Word (Black text on a white background, size 36,  and 100% zoom). The image will be cropped to the bounding box of the message.

[insert 20 test cases, 2 of each size between 1 and 10]

[insert link to test cases + reference images]

### Scoring:

`(% of characters right in test cases)*10 - code length`

(Highest score wins)

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- No catering to the test cases.

(Note that this is just a concept for a challenge. I will expand the challenge if this receives a positive response).

Comment: @EasterlyIrk The input is an image containing wingdings characters.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76320/fun-with-flags)

Comment: @KennyLau This is different because the test cases will have up to 10 characters in the same image (and catering to the test cases is a standard loophole). I'll work on this more tomorrow.

Comment: The description of the image seems underspecified to me. Will the characters all be the same font size? How will they be laid out? Colours? Anti-aliasing?

Comment: What is the [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) setting?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not completely sure, so it's probably at whatever the default for Windows 10 is. If needed I can run the images through a program that creates a 1-bit image.

Answer (score 2):

## KOTH: Black Hole

I've recently seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMLE7a3faI4) (by Tom Scott), in which it featured a game called Black Hole. Let's play that for KOTH!

#### Overview (the original version in the video)

- Two "players" have 10 counters, each labelled 1 to 10.
- These two players take it in turns to place counters in increasing order on a grid of 21 "spaces" arranged in a triangle (i.e. a triangle with 6 rows).
- Once all 21 counters have been placed, the remaining space that hasn't been used is the "black hole", and the dots surrounding the black hole are "sucked in".
- The person with the lowest sum of the counters "sucked in" wins.

**For the purpose of KOTH, the triangular grid will consist of 120 spaces (i.e. the triangle "pyramid" will be 15 rows high), and each player will have 59 counters (Yes, that means that there will be 2 black holes).**

#### Point System

- Win: 10 points, Draw (very rare): 3 points, Loss: no points

#### Instructions

- The bot must output a number between 1 and 120 each turn, and a "counter" with the same number as the current no. turn made by the bot will be placed there.
- After 118 turns, the black holes activate, the score is counted, and points are awarded.

**NOTE: If there is no output within 5 seconds, the bot immediately loses.**

#### "Battle" System

- The competition will be a round-robin, except each bot battles every other bot 5 times.
- The top three bots will then play each other 10 times each.
- The final winner is the winner of the competition.

#### Info on controller stuff

The controller will be in Python, but I don't have the first clue how to make an controller. Any help?

Comment: Well I think that you have to choose a way of inputting and outputting data first to have an idea how to write the controller. If it's going to be single language KOTH you can just ask people to write you functions/classes in some way and you can attach those to a regular program performing the game. On the other hand the challenge seems simple enough that you may just give the input as arguments to an execution of the programs and read output for them (calling an instance of the bot for each move).

Comment: Yeah... I'll probably do it as an input/output thing, regardless of language.

Comment: 1. I think you've changed the size of the board so many times that there are figures in the question from at least three different board sizes. 2. In the video, the counters must be placed in increasing order of value, but the question doesn't mention this anywhere. 3. From my experience of other koths, best-of-50 is going to be far too time-consuming. I suggest making it best-of-5 or at most best-of-7.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the tips... sorry if it's confusing. Will edit.

Comment: Interesting game. There is discussion about the [different options for input and output](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/what-is-the-best-method-to-communicate-with-koth-entries) on meta, and also there's a general [tips for writing KotHs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/tips-for-king-of-the-hill-challenges).

Comment: So... if there are multiple languages, will I have to install other things that can run those languages? That's a lot of stuff to prepare for, considering it's only for a short while (maybe for longer if I keep on doing KotHs).

Answer (score 2):

## Find point on the Hilbert curve

The [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) space filling curve. It is a limit of recursive approximations. Being spacefilling means there is a parametrization of the curve which is continuous. So we can map the interval `[0,1]` continuously to the unit square `[0,1]x[0,1]`. Let us call this map `h`. (Note that the image of the `[0,1]` is not the complete `[0,1]x[0,1]` but rather a dense subset. E.g. `(.5,.1)` is obviously not in the Hilbert curve, as it is not in any of the approximations.)

[image]

Your task is now to write a progarm that given a value in `[0,1]` to return the corresponding value unit square `[0,1]x[0,1]`, where `h(0)=(0,0)` and `h(1)=(1,0)`, and `h(.5) = (.5, .5)`

## Meta

- This could also be done backwards.
- Test cases to be added.

Comment: Are forwards and backwards sufficiently different tasks to make this two separate questions?

Comment: I just thought about this: the 'backwards' challenge would be relatively difficult, as `h` is continuous but only *injective*, but the inverse is not continuous anymore. So I think this direction is the better suited one for a challenge.

Comment: Yes the backwards challenge would have more than one valid output. Maybe 4? You could just ask for any 1, or all (4?) or as many as exist (I'm guessing the 4 corners have only one answer). Forwards seems more than enough of a challenge to start with though.

Comment: I'd recommend either a formula or a reference implementation to make the correct output explicit. The Hilbert curve is fairly easily confused with similar-but-not-quite-the-same curves.

Comment: @trichoplax Yes I'm certainly going to add a reference. What other curves do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of curves like the [Moore curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve) but now that I look it up, I see that answers using this would be ruled out by test cases using the end points (0 or 1).

Comment: Right, I was not aware of this curve and it certainly looks quite similar!

Comment: I really like it because its ends meet so it can form a closed loop.

Answer (score 2):

## Determine whether one graph is a subgraph of the other

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)[discrete-math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-math)

Given two unlabelled graphs as adjecency matrices with the same number of vertices, the goal is determining whether the first graph is a subgraph of the second one.

#### Definitions

A **graph** `G=(V,E)` comprises a set of vertices `V={1,2,3,...,n}` and a set of edges `E ⊆ V x V = {(u,v) | u,v ∈ V}`. The **adjecency matrix** `A={a(i,j)}`of a graph `G` is defined entry wise:`a(i,j) = 1 if (i,j) ∈ E, 0 otherwise`.

A graph `H=(W,F)` with adjecency matrix `B={b(i,j)}` is a **subgraph** of `G` iff all following statements hold:

- `V=W`
- There is a permutation `p:V→W=V` such that `b(p(i),p(j)) ≤ a(i,j) for all i,j ∈ V=W`

#### Examples

First the trivial ones:

- Obviously, every graph is a subgraph of itself.
- If `H` has more edges than `G` then it cannot be a subgraph.
- If you remove edges from a valid subgraph, the result will again be a subgraph.
- If every of the `n` nodes in `G` has edges to every other node, then every graph `H` with `n` nodes is a subgraph.

**6 vertices, isomorphic (one big cycle)** (remove some ones from Graph 1 in order to generate more valid subgraphs)

```
Permutation: [5 6 4 1 3 2]
Graph 1:     [0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 0 1;1 0 0 0 0 0]
Graph 2:     [0 0 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0;0 1 0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1;0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

#### Visualization of the above example by @KennyLau:

[image]

**10 vertices, same number of edges, non isomorphic (g1 has minimal cycles of length 3,4,5, g2 has minimal cycles of length 3,4,4**)

```
Graph 1:    [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
Graph 2:    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1;0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Sample input output?

Comment: I added some now.

Comment: @KennyLau How did create those visualizations?

Comment: Microsoft Paint.

Answer (score 2):

### Nested brackets in source code

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string)

---

### Introduction

This challenge is somewhat unusual.
Basically, your inputs are a correctly matched string of brackets **S** and a number **n ≥ 0**, and your output is the number of matched pairs at nesting level **n** in **S**.
The outermost pairs are at level 0, those inside them are at level 1, and so on.
The twist is that the string **S** is part of your source code, and incorrectly matched strings must result in compilation or runtime errors.

### The task

Your task is to write four strings, **A**, **B**, **L**, and **R**, that satisfy the following conditions.

- The strings **L** and **R** are non-empty and distinct. They represent a left and right bracket.
- If **S** is a concatenation of **L**s and **R**s that is correctly matched, then the concatenation **ASB** is a valid program (full runnable program or function definition) is your programming language of choice. It takes an integer **n ≥ 0** and outputs the number of **L**-**R** pairs in **S** at nesting level **n**.
- If **S** is a concatenation of **L**s and **R**s that is *not* correctly matched, then **ASB** either fails to compile, or throws an error on every possible input.

### Example

Suppose that the strings **A**, **B**, **L**, and **R** are `BEGIN;`, `END;`, `DO(i++;` and `);`, respectively, in an imaginary programming language.
Then the string `DO(i++;);DO(i++;DO(i++;););` is a correctly matched concatenation of **L**s and **R**s.
On input `0`, the program

```
BEGIN;DO(i++;);DO(i++;DO(i++;););END;
```

should output `2`, because there are two matched pairs at level 0.
However, the program

```
BEGIN;DO(i++;DO(i++;);END;
```

should result in an error, because the brackets are not correctly matched.

### More examples

Here is a table of some programs, inputs and expected outputs.

```
Program          Input  Output
------------------------------
AB               <any>  0
ALRB             0      1
ALRB             1      0
ALLRRB           1      1
ALRLRB           0      2
ALRLLRRB         0      2
ALRLLRRB         1      1
ALLRLLLRRRLRRLRB 0      2
ALLRLLLRRRLRRLRB 1      3
ALLRLLLRRRLRRLRB 2      1
ALLRLLLRRRLRRLRB 3      1
ALLRLLLRRRLRRLRB 4      0
ARB              <any>  error
ALB              <any>  error
ARLB             <any>  error
ALLRB            <any>  error
ALLRRRLRB        <any>  error
ALLRRLLRB        <any>  error
ALLRRRLLLRRB     <any>  error
```

### Rules and scoring

Your score is the sum of the lengths of the four strings, lower score being better.
You must identify the strings in your answer.
You are not allowed to read your source code directly or indirectly.
Standard loopholes are also disallowed.

---

### Sandbox notes

- Is the task of counting pairs on a nesting level too easy? I don't want it to be trivial, but not so hard either that it shadows the source layout aspect. A slightly more difficult variant would be to count the number of peaks (substrings **LR**) at nesting level **n**.
- Is the restriction of erroring on mismatched brackets interesting? I could also require the program to always return `-1` in this case, or something similar.

Comment: Shouldn't `DO(i++;);DO(i++;DO(i++;))` be `DO(i++;);DO(i++;DO(i++;););`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes it should, good catch.

Comment: Thought about this more. By making `A` end in `"`, `L` be `(`, `R` be `)`, and `B` start with `"`, I can reduce it to matching brackets in a string. If it's not a duplicate of an existing question, it has at least neutered the twist.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's a valid approach, but I'm hoping that more quine-like solutions will be shorter, at least in "normal" languages. The error rule is intended to help with that too.

Answer (score 2):

## Three Indistinguishable Dice

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given three dice rolls (integer values from 1-6) in sorted order (so as to be indistinguishable), write a program that converts them to the sum of two dice with an identical distribution.

Inspired by [standupmath's The Three Indistinguishable Dice Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E). A follow-up ["solution" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBBftD7gq7Y) was also posted, but arguing about "elegance" of one way or another is a bit subjective. Counting characters isn't. `:D`

### Details

- Score is the length of the program in characters
- The program can be a function that's called somehow, or executable script that reads from stdin, or whatever's convienent.
- No "rerolling" by getting entropy from another source

### Example Test Code

Rather than doing any sort of probabilistic testing, it's easy enough to rip through the 216 (6<sup>3</sup>) cases of all the three dice and assert that your function returns each value as many times as it should. It will be called with identical parameters (e.g. the cases `1, 2, 3` and `3, 2, 1`, ... are presumed indistinguishable and are (arbitrarily) converted to `1, 2, 3`).

The below is in Python, written hopefully generically enough to be clear to port. If your language of choice uses stdin/stdout, it would be a bit different. The testing code is just for testing and not scored (though if you want to provide it for other users of your language or I/O method, that might be useful).

```
from thing import f

# this is the fair distribution of the sum of two dice, 
# multiplied by 6 (because each should be hit 6x more)
dist = {
    2: 6,   12: 6,
    3: 12,  11: 12,
    4: 18,  10: 18,
    5: 24,   9: 24,
    6: 30,   8: 30,
    7: 36,
}

d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in d:
    for j in d:
        for k in d:
            ijk = sorted([i, j, k])
            result = f(ijk)
            dist[result] -= 1

for key in dist:
    assert dist[key] == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck-golf: find the maximum of two numbers

[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)

You will be provided with two numbers on the first two memory cells, and you will write a code in brainfuck to put the maximum of the two numbers on the third memory cell.

- You may use [this template](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrPisrKysrPA==) and [this template](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrKys+KysrPA==) to test your code. Just append your code to the templates.
- You may destroy the numbers in the first two cells.
- The pointer must initially point to the first cell.
- The two initial numbers will be positive.
- `,` will halt your program (waits for input which I will not supply).
- The tape is semi-infinite. Your numbers are on the first two memory cells.
- The cells do not wrap around. They just increase until the number is bigger than the age of the universe in terms of picoseconds.

Comment: Language specific challenges are generally frowned upon. And if this wasn't restricted to BF, it would be to trivial.

Comment: How is regex-golf different from this?

Comment: Regex-golf is slightly different since there are many versions of regex with different behavior. But hey, I could be wrong. We've had BF only challenges before. (such as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33019/brainfuck-sorting, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/bitwise-operators-in-brainfuck, and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/implement-quicksort-in-brainf I'd leave it up for a while and see what other people think.

Comment: It may be a duplicate of the first linked challenge, because this challenge is only about comparing...

Comment: Can we use `,`, and if so what will it do (e.g. set to 0, set to -1, no change)?

Comment: Since this is a) language specific, b) asks for a snippet, c) asks for a task that is probably often just a minor component of a more elaborate program, how about posting it as a tips question instead?

Comment: You should also specify the details of the Brainfuck interpreter. Semi-infinite or infinite tape? Byte values or arbitrary-precision integers in the cells? Etc...

Comment: Why [tag:tips]?

Answer (score 2):

## Do my algebra homework for me!

*Inspired by a true story*

Ugh, my maths teacher gave me so much homework on quadratics.

Two whole worksheets, filled with equations like `Expand (x+1)(x-6)` and `Factorize x^2-2x+1`. I already hate it.

Suddenly, a lightbulb appeared out of nowhere, and landed about five centimetres above my head.

A stroke of thought went through me: Why not write a piece of code down instead of all those stupid answers? It would save me tons of time!

So here's the task: Make an algebra solver for me! To save my hand from breaking, the code needs to be as short as possible.

### Instructions:

- Given an input in the form `expand/factorize equation`, return the algebraic equation:

  - Expanded, if the keyword (the first word) is `expand` (e.g. `expand (x+1)(x+6)` would return `x^2+7x+6`), or
  - Factorized, if the keyword is `factorize` (e.g. `factorize x^2+9x+14` would return `(x+2)(x+7)`.
- The equation will be quadratic, in the form `ax^2+bx+c` or `(x+d)(x+e)` (`a` to `e` are all placeholders, while `x` is the variable - the variable can be any letter from `a` to `z` - so an equation like `expand (a+3)(b+6)` would still hold).
- With an expansion equation that contains two or more unknowns (e.g. `expand (a+3)(b+6)`), place the letters in the summands with two or more letters in alphabetical order, and place the remaining summands in alphabetical order (so the previous example would equal `ab+6a+3b+18`).

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

### Meta

- Any dupes?
- I probably need a better title. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Duplicate of expansion.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80030/discrete-convolution-or-polynomial-multiplication)

Comment: [Very related to factorization](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/resolve-quadratic-equation).

Comment: Drat, foiled by previous questions! So, there's nothing I can really do, right?

Answer (score 2):

## Shortest program with unknown halting status

### Rules

1. Post a term on the [binary λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_lambda_calculus) (BLC) whose termination is unknown.
2. If someone proves that your term does or doesn't terminate, you entry is disqualified.
3. The term with the smallest number of bits on the BLC wins.

Don't forget to also post a quick description of what you did and the original source code, otherwise we will just have to trust your random string meets the specs!

### Example submission

```
Size: 579 bits

Program: 01001001000100010001000101100111101111001110010101000001110011101000000111001110
10010000011100111010000001110011101000000111001110100000000111000011100111110100
00101011000000000010111011100101011111000000111001011111101101011010000000100000
10000001011100000000001110010101010101010111100000011100101010110000000001110000
00000111100000000011110000000001100001010101100000001110000000110000000100000001
00000000010010111110111100000010101111110000001100000011100111110000101101101110
00110000101100010111001011111011110000001110010111111000011110011110011110101000
0010110101000011010
```

**Explanation:** this term, if it terminates, reduces to a list with all church-encoded natural numbers of the sequence of Collatz ([A006577](https://oeis.org/A006577)) from 0 to 2^256. It is not known if `collats(n)` halts for all `n`; we only know up to about `2^64`, so my submission satisfies the specification. For a longer explanation, I've set [this repository](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/unknown_halting_status). The original code was written on Caramel and also on the repository. Here is a brief:

```
-- Receives fix and a natural, returns the number of
-- recursive calls until the collatz function halts.
collatz fix n = (fix go n)

    -- The recursive search
    go go n = (succ (even_odd_or_leq_one n even odd leq1))
        even = (go go (half n))
        odd  = (go go (succ (mul n 3)))
        leq1 = 0
```

Comment: The only thing I'd like to comment on is that the challenge shouldn't be limited to BLC, and that other languages should be allowed so long as they are valid. For example, there is no reason to disallow a python solution that does the same thing as the above BLC code.

Comment: I agree with @Zwei, but also ban IO and other nondeterministic code.

Comment: As commented on main, you need to define the system of axioms which are permitted for the proof.

Comment: Fair enough. I feel like this will never get enough momentum for any relevant answer, though. I might just not ask it.

Comment: @Dokkat This challenge is interesting imo, there are just a few things that need to be worked out such as how does one prove that a program does or does not terminate. Remove the BLC only rule and define the axiom system and this challenge should be good for main.

Comment: I think it's better to keep the language restriction.

Comment: @feersum for what reason?

Comment: @Zwei the whole point of the challenge is that I want the program with the lowest Kolmogorov Complexity. It is hard to talk about this metric when you don't have a fixed language. There is a very clear and trivial measure of the complexity of a term on the binary lambda calculus. In fact, I'd say the only way for a code golf challenge to be an objective competition (not just a popularity contest) is by using a fixed language with a clear complexity metric, and the BLC is about as good as we know.

Comment: @Dokkat fair enough.

Comment: That link is to binary combinatory logic, not binary lambda calculus.

Answer (score 2):

## Maximal root multiplicity of integer polynomials

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) [polynomial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomial)

Given a non constant polynomial with integer coefficients, determine the maximal multiplicity of it's (perhaps complex) roots.

#### Definitions

**Multiplicity:** Let `p` be a polynomial with complex coefficients and `x0` some complex number. If `x0` is a root, it is said to have multiplicity `n` if `p(x) = a(x) * (x-x0)^n` where `a` is another (complex) polynomial such that `(x-x0)` does not divide `a`. If `x0` is not a root it is defined to have multiplicity `0`. Note that the polynomials we consider do only have integral coefficients (consider the integers as a subset of the complex numbers).

**Maximal Multiplicity:** Let `x0,...,xk` be the roots of of `p`,then the maximal multiplicity of `p` is defined as the maximal multiplicity of `xi` for `i=0,...,k`.

#### I/O

For the input and output, the polynomials can be written in any convenient format, e.g. also as a (variable length) list of coefficients.

#### Hints

A polynomial has a root of multiplicity greater than one if and only if it shares a root with it's derivative. This can e.g. be checked with the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_polynomial).

#### Examples

```
polynomial     maximal multiplicity
1              0
x^7-1          1
x^8-x^7-x-1    2
x^3-3x^2+3x-1  3
```

Comment: What sorts of builtins are allowed/banned? Root finding? Polynomial GCD?

Comment: I did not plan to ban anything, would you suggest banning these?

Comment: Not really, it's fine if nothing's banned. Just making sure it was considered :)

Comment: Do you have any test cases for roots which repeat in different irreducible factors and thus demonstrate that it can't be done by counting multiplicity of irreducible factors?

Comment: Answering my own question: it *can* be done by counting multiplicity of irreducible factors, because the minimal polynomial of an algebraic number is a factor of any polynomial of which that number is a root. So [factor to irreducibles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38513/194) is worth mentioning as related, although it's far more than needed.

Comment: I considered factoring as the *obvious* approach but I think most languages do not have the means to calculate with exact complex numbers (except some CAS' like Mathematica), so the method via resultants/discriminants should just provide *another* way, which surprisingly only needs integer arithmetic.

Comment: The line on maximal multiplicity ends rather abruptly, I'd assume that that was an accident? Anyway, I'm not sure the terminology "does not divide" is correct here. It's been a while for me, but I think you should say something like: "does not divide a(x) such that the quotient is a polynomial"?

Comment: Right, I think I wanted to add something regarding the constant polynomials, but now I excluded those too for the sake of simplicity. Statements about *divisibility* usually only make sense in the context of rings, and is defined as: *A divides B if there is a C such that B = AC*. As soon as you consider a field (in your example the field of rational functions) the *divisibility* becomes trivial, as any nonzero element divides every element of the field.

Comment: The method via factoring only requires integer arithmetic. I don't find it at all surprising that an approach with resultants only needs integer arithmetic, because subresultants are the standard efficient way to do polynomial GCD.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree, the "surprisingness" is subjective, as far as I know the resultants are usually defined via the product of the differences of the zeros. From that perspective it isn't really obvious that this might result in something even real=) Regarding the factoring we probably did not have the same thing in mind or I do not understand what you mean. I thought about factoring into linear factors, which generally results in general algebraic numbers, far from integers. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Factoring to polynomials which are irreducible over the integers, as in the linked question. Equivalently, as I realised between my first and second comment, factoring to the minimal polynomials of the roots. Edit: ah, but wait. Can the minimal polynomial contain the root multiple times?

Comment: I'm not sure in general, I think this might fail for some fields with finite characteristic, but for algebraic numbers (=elements of finite field extensions of the rational numbers) the minimal polynomials have distinct roots in the corresponding splitting field.

Answer (score 2):

### Determine the winner of Beggar my Neighbour

The card game Beggar my Neighbour is boring in that the final outcome is entirely determined by the initial arrangement of the deck, so long as certain rules are followed for the order in which cards are picked up from the playing field and moved to decks.

### The Game

1. Both players are dealt 26 cards.
2. Players play their top card alternately, starting with the player who won the previous stack or Player 1 at the beginning of the game.
3. Play is interrupted when either player plays a picture card. In that case their opponent must play a number of cards equal to the value of the picture card above 10, i.e. Jack = 1, Queen = 2, King = 3, Ace = 4. The player then wins all the played cards which are returned to the bottom of their hand, unless the opponent themselves plays a picture card, in which case this rule interrupts their play.
4. If at any point one of the players needs to draw a card from their deck, but their deck is empty, they immediately lose the game.

### Example play

Player 1 starts with 7; Player 2 plays 3; subsequent plays are 9; 9; T; A; 6, J; A; 2, 3, 7, 6: Player 2 adds the cards 7399TA6JA2376 to his deck.
Player 2 starts: J; K; 9, 4, A; 5, 2, J; 2: Player 1 adds the cards JK94A52J2 to his deck.
Player 1 starts: 6; T; T; 5; 9; A; A; 3, K; K; 7, Q; 5, T: Player 1 adds the cards 6TT59AA3KK7Q5T to his deck.

### The Challenge

Given two lists of cards in the players' decks, in any convenient format, output a truthy value if Player 1 wins, and a falsey value if Player 2 wins.

For convenience, a 10 card will be represented with a T, and face cards will be abbreviated (Ace -> A, King -> K, Queen -> Q, Jack -> J), so that all cards are one character long. Alternatively, ranks may be represented with decimal integers 2-14 (Jack -> 11, Queen -> 12, King -> 13, Ace -> 14) or hex digits 2-E (10 -> A, Jack -> B, Queen -> C, King -> D, Ace -> E). Since suits don't matter, suit information will not be given.

You may assume that all games will terminate at some point (though it may take a very long time), and one player will always run out of cards before the other.

There are variations for more than two players but they will not be considered here.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82340/determine-the-winner-of-a-game-of-war

Answer (score 2):

Still to-do:

1. <s>Add more test cases</s>
2. <s>Make input requirements a little looser</s>
3. <s>Make output requirements looser</s>
4. <s>Specify that a full program is *not* required</s>
5. Change the name of gem-elements maybe?
6. Come up with a title
7. Come up with a cool story

---

I saw this as a problem over on CodeReview, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61242/71148) is the original question. I thought it would be fun to golf.

---

> You have discovered various rocks. Each rock is composed of various elements, and each element is represented by a lowercase letter from '`a`' to '`z`'. The same element can be present multiple times in a rock. An element is called a 'common-element' if it occurs at least once in each of the rocks. Given the list of rocks you have to determine how many different kinds of common-elements you have.

## Input Format

- Each rock is a string which consists of lowercase letters from '`a`' to '`z`' representing elements
- You can take the strings in whatever way is easy for you (lines from STDIN, pipe delimited STDIN, array of strings as a method param, etc.)

## Output Format

- The number of different types of common-elements for the given list of rocks. This can be as an integer or string

## Constraints

- There will always be at least one rock
- Each rock will always have at least one element
- You do *not* need to make a full program (functions & methods are allowed)

## Sample Input

```
abcdde
baccd
eeabg
```

## Sample Output

```
2
```

### Explanation

Only '`a`' and '`b`' are common-elements since these are the only characters that occur in each of the rocks' composition.

## More test cases

```
a

0
```

```
aa

0
```

```
aa
aa

1
```

```
zyxabc

0
```

```
abc
def

0
```

```
abc
a

1
```

```
abc
ab
cb

1
```

```
abc
cba

3
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

26
```

```
defabc
bfgcde
chfgde
gedfhi
fgiejh

2
```

Comment: `N` doesn't seem to actually be a useful input, so I'd consider making it optional. In addition, tight I/O requirements are usually frowned upon, I'd consider modifying it to allow any format that doesn't add any additional information. I'd also recommend removing the quote block, and adding at least one test case with `N=1` and one where the result itszero. Good luck with your challenge and thanks for using the sandbox! :)

Comment: Also can we take the input in the default list/array format for our language? As FryAmTheEggman, good luck with the challenge!

Comment: How do I say "any format that doesn't add additional information" in a way that doesn't sound silly? Is that fine as-is?

Comment: Nice edits, looking much better! If you want an example of a nice way to word the preamble, you could try emulating [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87405/31625). I think "any reasonable format" is a fine way to say what you want, but what you have is fine, too.

Comment: This might be fun to golf in Java, but in the languages which are predominantly used on this site nowadays it's two built-ins and something like 3 to 6 characters depending on the language, so it's actually a pretty boring question.

Answer (score 2):

### Pareto frontier

A point (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) *dominates* another point (x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>) if both x<sub>1</sub>≥x<sub>2</sub> and y<sub>1</sub>≥y<sub>2</sub>. A set of points is a [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) if no point dominates another point. In other words, any increase in one coordinate must be met with a decrease in the other coordinate.

Your task is to decide whether a given set of points is a Pareto frontier.

**Input:** A collection of two or more points, which are pairs of positive integers. No two points will have the same x-value or the same y-value. You may not assume the points are given in a particular order.

**Output:** A consistent Truthy value if it is, and a consistent Falsey value if it's not.

*True:*

```
[(12, 1), (6, 4)]
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
[(4, 4), (3, 8), (12, 3), (20, 1)]
[(106, 106), (107, 102), (104, 127)]
```

*False:*

```
[(5, 9), (4, 8)]
[(1, 1), (11, 11)]
[(5, 3), (2, 4), (7, 7), (1, 2)]
[(15, 2), (7, 8), (4, 14), (6, 6)]
```

---

**Sandbox:**

- Is it better to do the decision problem, or the filtering problem of finding the upper Pareto frontier of non-dominated points?
- Should the input be allowed to be taken pre-zipped, as two lists of n numbers? What about a 2D 2-by-n array versus an n-by-2 array?

Comment: I'd recommend only doing the filtering problem if there is a nicer solution than subsets -> filter on decision -> take longest that you can enforce with restraints of some kind. Otherwise I feel like it might be kind of chameleon-y.

Comment: The decision problem can be done as filter and check equality; or sort on one axis and check that the other axis is in reverse order. The filter problem can be done by filtering the power set with the decision problem and taking the longest; or by folding a removal of dominated points. IMO the filter problem is more interesting, because sort builtins are very common and typically cheap.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The largest Pareto-incomparable subset might contain points dominated by the rest of the set. I expect filtering would be done by folding removal. Does that affect your opinion?

Comment: Ah, true. Folding removal still seems more interesting to me than sorting and checking reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

### Reversing the Game of Life

Though computing successive generations of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) may seem simple enough, reversing the process is not.

Given an initial board configuration in Conway's Game of Life, either return a predecessor, or some value indicating that it is a [*Garden of Eden*](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/Garden_of_Eden) (and therefore contains an *orphan*), meaning it has no predecessor. A *predecessor* is a previous generation of a board configuration, meaning that after running the game for a some number of generations, you will arrive at the successor generation, the board configuration that you were initially given.

Any given configuration may have zero or more predecessors. Some have infinitely many, such as still life patterns.

It will probably be simplest to find a *parent*, a predecessor configuration from the preceding generation, such that reaching the successor takes one generation.

[image: Two parents of the Block]

If given a state bounded by a 6x6 rectangle, for example, a parent (if any) will be found by searching the 8x8 rectangle around it. **This is a fastest-code challenge**, since brute force solutions would take a long time, even for relatively small inputs.

> All Game of Life patterns bounded by a 6x6 rectangle have a predecessor. <sup>[Source](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/orphan.html)</sup>

---

**Example Input**

Input can be how you like. If you prefer a list of active points, or a matrix of Booleans, that's fine. Just make your output be the same format.

This input represents a block:

[image: Block still life]

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

[[1,1],
 [1,1]]
```

The original Garden of Eden:

[image: Garden of Eden]

All cells outside the image are dead (white).

---

**Example Output:**

This is a parent to the block.

```
[[1,0,0,1],
 [0,1,1,0]]
```

Garden of Eden:

```
No predecessor
```

---

**Resources:**

- [Golly Game of Life Home Page](http://golly.sourceforge.net/) - A powerful implementation of the game
- [Garden of Eden / Orphan](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/orphan.html) - History
- [Garden of Eden (cellular automaton)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton)) - Wikipedia: Info on orphans
- [Reversing the Game of Life for Fun and Profit](https://nbickford.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/reversing-the-game-of-life-for-fun-and-profit/) - **Algorithms**

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life)

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but searching for a parent was how I approached [an earlier fastest-code game-of-life question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10592/194).

Comment: Why is it undecidable? Theoretically, you could just enumerate over every possible parent state until one generates the pattern (or you run out of possible parents in the case of a Garden of Eden).

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I don't understand either, but from the linked Wikipedia article: *For one-dimensional cellular automata, orphans and Gardens of Eden can be found by an efficient algorithm, but for higher dimensions this is an undecidable problem. Nevertheless, computer searches have succeeded in finding these patterns in Conway's Game of Life.*

Comment: I think it's saying that there is no way that a decidable AND efficient algorithm exists? Not sure.

Comment: @mbomb007 Maybe it's talking about polynomial-time algorithms or something, last time I checked, bruteforce wasn't undecidable

Comment: @LegionMammal978 K, I'll remove that part. Is there enough explanation, do you think? There is probably required reading from the links I provided in order for a decent non-brute-force solution to be developed.

Comment: @mbomb007 Looks fine to me

Comment: I feel like the performance of an algorithm will heavily depend on how test cases are generated. You should specify this.

Comment: @LegionMammal978: The "undecidable" part is *probably* due to how you can have spaceships crash together from a distance to make new patterns.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman However, all that matters for finding the *previous* generation is the part of the spaceship within the n+2 X m+2 box that can affect the pattern

Comment: @LegionMammal978: Hmm, true. I don't know either.

Comment: @LegionMammal978, the undecidable problem is "*Given the rules for a 2-dimensional cellular automaton, does any Garden of Eden exist with those rules?*"

Comment: @PeterTaylor See the [Garden of Eden theorem](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/Garden_of_Eden#Garden_of_Eden_theorem). It says that any CA with multiple patterns that evolve to the same pattern must contain some Garden of Eden (presumably by a variant of the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: @xnor Do you think it'd be better to have something less reliant on test cases, like "given `n` and `m`, either return a Garden of Eden of size n by m or a falsey value if none exists"? I'm not really sure how to get test cases other than using the list of already known Gardens of Eden, plus some other GoL structures.

Comment: Other similar/related challenges could also be made, such as a code-golf: "given a Garden of Eden, return an orphan that it contains", or maybe optimizing for a specific category of dimensions, like "find the smallest Garden of Eden with a height of one and a width of `n`, if one exists."

Comment: @mbomb007 One way to do the test cases would be random grids. Most of these would likely have many predecessors and be doable with a heuristic search. If you want hard examples, maybe it's possible to generate ones with few predecessors and mix in gardens of eden. I don't know how doable that is. For returning a g.o.e. in an mxn grid, can't one just return a known minimal one if it fits and falsey otherwise? Generating optimal gardens of eden seems really hard even if you have  good heuristics.

Comment: @LegionMammal978, so the existence of twins is logically also undecidable, but I'm not sure why you think that's important to point out.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7208/34718)

Answer (score 2):

## Lets play Stratego!

Stratego is a game of imperfect information which centers around strategy foresight and deception.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratego

Your mission should you choose to accept it. is to write a bot which either uses polymorphism in a java class file, and/or communicate with the arena via an stdin/stdout wrapper.

The arena code and/or stdin out wrapper will be made available if there is interest. Here is the summary.

---

### Piece Summary

```
? = Unkown enemy piece
lowercase characters = your pieces
Upper case or special characters (!@#$%^&*()) or F B is the enemy pieces
f or F represents an immobile flag if the enemy moves on to this square it is game over.
b or B represents an immobile if any hostile piece steps on to it then it dies. If an enemy miner (8) steps on it will succesfully defuse or capture the bomb.
s or S gets killed when attacked by any piece, but can kill the 10 by stepping on it.
9 or ) can move any number of squares orthagonally.
Otherwise all pieces can capture pieces with a higher number than themselves. I.E 1 captures two which captures three which captures a 4 which captures a five etc...
When you attack a piece, the values of both pieces are revealed (thus the enemy will no longer see a "?") If the attacking piece is stronger it takes the spot, if it is weaker, it dies and the defender remains unharmed, and if they are equal both disappear.
```

Spaces empty are indicated with a space. Spaces with an impassable lake are indicated with an L. The wikipedia article has some great sample strategies and explanations. The protocol for communication will involve Outputting four zero indexed coordinates for the start and end locations of a piece. Invalid moves will simply result in no action taken.

Comment: do you have a bot API?

Comment: Not yet. It was something I was pondering in my head. If there is any interest in this I can slap together an api. @AgentCrazyPython do you think this is a doable challenge

Comment: I think it's doable. You'd get a whole ton of rep for it.

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython lol I need the rep. I will write up an arena controller. Should I do it through an stdin/stdout interface or an abstract class? I think I will first write an interface that allows you to inherit from an abstract class. Than I would write a wrapper. The only thing is that I have no clue how to go about implementing a sample bot.

Comment: depends on if you want to let one language or all languages. I think you should go just one langauge: JS. JS can be demoed easily in the browser and it's great for writing bots. the spacewar! challenge is a good example

Comment: I need to learn JS, but I am slightly discouraged after learning about jsf*** lol. It seems like an <s>odd</s> unique language lol.

Comment: I will first prototype a Java arena, and then I will first write a wrapper (probably by modifying @Moogie 's) wrapper. Then I will stare at a wall idly considering porting it to Java script.

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython ^ Forgot to ping you on the above comments

Comment: js is super easy to learn. JS has really similar syntax

Comment: Yeah, but the dynamic typing stuff really gets me. I do have some python background which should help, but I am I java dev mainly. @Agent CrazyPython That being said, I will try to learn java as stack snippets do appeal to me.

Comment: java ≠ javascript!!!!!!! why is dynamic typing hard - it's looser than static typing

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython I know that JS!=Java lol. THats why I am scared of it.  For someone reason I do prefer being sure of type safety as I code rather than at run time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42930/discussion-between-rohan-jhunjhunwala-and-agent-crazypython).

Answer (score 2):

[Do X without Y​](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86668/do-x-without-y/) again!

Here is an X done with Y:

```
YyYy        YyYy
 YyYy      YyYy 
  YyYy    YyYy  
   YyYy  YyYy   
    YyYyYyYy    
     YyYyYy     
     yYyYyY     
    yYyYyYyY    
   yYyY  yYyY   
  yYyY    yYyY  
 yYyY      yYyY 
yYyY        yYyY
```

As you can see, there are 92 Y/ys in this X. Conveniently, there are also exactly 92 printable ASCII characters in the range ! to ~ if you exclude Y and y. Your challenge is to write a program to output or a function to return the above X with all the Y/ys replaced by any permutation of those 92 characters. Leading and trailing white space is permitted. Shortest code wins!

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: Should that say "each of those 92 characters" (in the range ! to ~, excluding Yy)?

Comment: Just [drop the exclamation mark already](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8090/48934).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but you seem to be requiring all answers to be exactly 92 characters long and within that constraint aiming to be the shortest...

Comment: @PeterTaylor: He doesn't specify a length of an answer... He says that in the above ascii X each Y is replaced by another character of the 92 printable characters that are not y or Y; each char is only used once.

Comment: I'd make it obvious that a *permutation* of the 92 characters are to be used (no repeating a character)

Comment: Have you abandoned this altogether already?

Comment: @LeakyNun It only got 1 upvote, unless you know a better way of telling when it's ready.

Answer (score 2):

## The Enemy's Gate is Down! (Ender's Game)

### Please note this is a work in progress

Your challenge should you choose to accept it is to play ender's game to win [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) style, in honor of Martin Ender first receiving 100k rep! You will split up into teams. You are red if you are an even post and blue if you are odd.

Here is a simplified ascii representation of the map.

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W       1                        F                         2    W
W                  WwW                                          W
W        WWW                                                    W
W                                            WWWWWWWW           W
W                WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW                              W  
W                                                               W  
W                                                               W  
W             WWWWWWWWW                    WWWWWWWWWWW          W  
W                                                               W  
W                              WWWWW                            W  
W                                                               W
W       3                        G                         4    W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Your gate is represented by the "F" and the enemies gate is "G". W's represent walls which will be arranged in an unbiased distribution. The goal is to get to the enemies gate first. Each turn you will output a number from 0-15.

```
 0-7 will allow you to "push" off of a block assuming there is a block in the 8 blocks closest to you (orthagonally or diagonally")
8-17 allows you to shoot a bullet in a given direction which will continue to travel in a given direction. 
It will break upon hitting a wall or another player. The bullet represented by "P" on the ascii map is iterated after each step. Any player that drifts into it will also be killed. 

Directions

567
4U0
321
```

The winning team is the team which either captures the flag first the last man (bot/woman) standing!

All submission are deterministic java programs. A psuedorandom generator will be provided. The winning team is the team which wins the first game, (if there are ties).

Games will be halted after a significant number (1000) turns. I may allow multiple copies of the same bot on each team to make it more interesting.

Collisions with players are treated like collisions with walls.

Comment: What about collisions between players?

Comment: Both die (i guess)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon a

Comment: Would it be possible to add an Stdin/out wrapper?

Comment: What if friendly bots can be in the same square, and push off each other to confuse the enemy? That seems cool. Probably make it so it doesn't affect the non-pushing bot just to reduce troublemaker bots ;) (Also, I guess each player would need an indication that they have a teammate in the same square or something)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon ok I can make it so all players atreated like walls u can push off of.

Comment: It would be nice for the programs to be able to be in any language (using subprocess pipe)

Comment: @Blue I can write  an stdin/stdout wrapper once I get an arena. The onl issue is that by starting subproceses the performance may be significantly harmed

Answer (score 2):

## Golf an InterpretMe interpreter (in any language other than InterpretMe)

This is a very simple challenge.

The joke language InterpretMe consists of one command; `*`, which causes the program to take input of an InterpretMe program and execute it. An InterpretMe  program will interpret as many InterpretMe programs as there are `*` in input. Your goal is to create a program that interprets InterpretMe in as few bytes as possible.

Test cases consist not of input and output, but input and termination. A newline denotes a new input to be interpreted as InterpretMe.

```
1. *   (executes input as an interpret me program, finishes)
2. *   (^same)
3. **  (executes input as an interpret me program, then does this again after the first program is done, finishes)
4. hi  (nothing, first star of previous line finishes)
5. **  (same as the other two star line)
6. hi  (nothing, first star of previous line finishes)
7. hi  (nothing, second star of line 5 finishes, so second star of line 3 finishes, so line 2 finishes, so line one finishes)
[termination]
```

```
hi  (does nothing and finishes)
[termination]
```

```
*hi  (executes inputted program, finishes)
*yo  (executes inputted program, finishes)
hey  (nothing)
[termination]
```

#### Sandbox

How can I make this challenge more clear? I understand that this challenge is simple, but that is part of the point; it sees how small a program can be for this purpose

Comment: To make the challenge more clear, you could supply the specification for the language which has to be interpreted. It shouldn't be necessary for each answerer to search for the basic definition of the problem.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Excuse me, it's right there. 
`An InterpretMe interpreter takes input, and runs an InterpretMe interpreter (which takes new input) as many times as "*" occurs in input.` (dumb blockquotes)

Comment: Maybe if you state up front that it's a joke language that would prime the reader to not expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## I wanna be the very best...

Wow, there's so many Pokemon in my Pokedex! Well, there seems too many... I wish there was some good way of sorting all of them!

Can you help?

Given a list of Pokemon with their stats - level and HP - and a sorting criterion, output the sorted list.

An example input would be:

```
([["Squirtle", 2, 10], ["Charizard", 58, 140], ["Mew", 75, 160], ["Pichu", 10, 25]], "alphabetical")
```

As you can see, each Pokemon is shown like so:

```
[pokemon_name, level, hp]
```

There are three sorting options:

- `"alphabetical"`: The Pokemon are sorted alphabetically.

  - If two or more Pokemon have identical names, then they are sorted by level, then HP.
- `"level"`: The Pokemon are sorted by level.

  - If two or more Pokemon have the same level, then they are sorted alphabetically, then by HP.
- `"hp"`: The Pokemon are sorted by HP.

  - If two or more Pokemon have the same HP, then they are sorted alphabetically, then by level.

## Specs:

- You are guaranteed that:

  - The `hp` and `level` of every Pokemon are integers.
  - The `level` of a Pokemon will not exceed 100.
  - The `hp` will not exceed 200.

If two or more Pokemon share all stats, then they can be arranged however you like.

The output will be the sorted list.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

## Meta:

- Is the challenge too easy/hard?
- Any improvements to my explanation?

Comment: Could you perhaps add some test cases? Also, since you haven't mentioned it I'm assuming the input is unrestricted? (I.e. we're allowed to use an array as parameter, a comma-separated string, a list, etc. Everyone's own choice?) And one very important question, does the list potentially include [all 721 Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) (with more incoming in generation 7..)

Comment: I think this challenge is pretty chameleon-y. I'm not sure if there is a dupe target floating around, but even if it isn't a dupe I'm not convinced this adds very much to the basic sorting challenges.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It can contain anything, really - it could contain all 721 Pokemon available, but it doesn't have to contain Pokemon at all.

Comment: @DerpfacePython I know, it's just a string. My last question was kinda a sarcastic one.. :)

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

### Make a Four Color Map

The [Four Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) states that it is possible to color any map separated into contiguous regions using only four colors such that no two adjacent regions are the same color. While the Five Color Theorem [has been proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_color_theorem#Outline_of_the_proof_by_contradiction), no proof exists for only using four colors (though there have also been no counterexamples). Given an image containing white regions separated by black borders, generate a four color map. You may assume that the borders of the image are also region borders and that shared corners do not count as adjacencies.

Related: [Four Color Theorem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40339/four-color-theorem)

## Input

An image in a standard format containing white regions separated by black borders

## Output

Displaying or writing an image file in any standard format that contains the original image colored according to the Four Color Theorem

## Examples

Your colorings do not need to match mine, they just need to be valid solutions
[image] ====> [image]
[image] ====> [image]

Note that the map of the US is not colored by state, it is colored by contiguous borders

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

Comment: Isn't the first example invalid? I see two adjacent red regions in the bottom left.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, I'll fix that.

Comment: I thought the four-color one was definitively proven a couple years ago?

Comment: It might have been, I was just going off of wikipedia. I just read the [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html) on it and it looks like it was proven for maps that are flat (and maybe all maps?) but I don't 100% follow it so not positive.

Comment: 1. The four colour theorem was proven in the 70s. 2. This is essentially a dupe of [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37709/194) but with a really bad input format.

Comment: Here's the [relevant Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Proof_by_computer) if you're looking for more info on the proof

Comment: The theorem was "disproved" by counterexample on some mailing list I believe.  It was a joke. Someone produced a pretty complex map and claimed that it couldn't be colored with only 4 colors. I think he was just seeing if he could get people to waste time looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

Your job is to take an input like below:

> Hello, world!
>
> π is cool!

and output it as a series of `<kbd>`.

Every character, including enter and space get their own [`<kbd>` HTML element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_kbd.asp), like so:

> <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>NEWLINE</kbd>
>
> <kbd><kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd></kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

Other characters like space and newline that are invisible **and** typeable (so no option, command, control, function, escape, delete, arrow keys, etc.) are all uppercase, like <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>NEWLINE</kbd>. <kbd>OPT</kbd> is an exception because it is used to create new characters. The code for these characters are:

```
<kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>NEWLINE</kbd>
```

Special characters needing to be typed using option use the following format <kbd><kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd></kbd> instead of <kbd>π</kbd>. The following code is used for these:

```
<kbd><kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd></kbd>
```

The same applies to characters that are typed using <kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd></kbd>.

We're assuming this is a QWERTY layout computer.

Here are the available option keys:

[image: Option keys]

Any of the orange keys are not allowed in this.

Here are the <kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys:

[image: Option shift keys]

Comment: +1 for well laid out challenge -1 for being mac specific

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala It's not technically Mac-specific, but rather uses the same shortcut keys to type special characters as a Mac.

Comment: Yeah, Ina all seriousness here have an upvote, It does seem like targetting  the opt key may be somewhat confusing for some S̶a̶n̶e̶ pc users.

Comment: For each letter you check which of the three character sets it is in then add some fixed strings to it. It doesn't seem to me like there is much interesting stuff to do in there? I'm not sure this adds much to the other keyboard focused challenges that we have.

Comment: Do all of those characters even *have* Unicode codepoints?

Answer (score 2):

## How synchronized are my clocks?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I have two clocks, *A* and *B*, and A always shows the exact time, however B is off by a certain amount of time, that I'd like to find out. (I know A and B run at the exact same speed.) I cannot read the exact time of both simultaneously, that means I can only switch back and forth and read the time sequentially. (For the sake of simplicity, both show their time as a real number (lets say hours), and each real number encodes an unique point in time.)

So here is an example: `B: 1, A: 3, A: 5, B: 4.5`. We see because of the first two entries `B: 1, A: 3` that B is behind A by at most 2 hours, and that because of the last two entries `A: 5, B: 4.5` we see that B is behind A by at least half an hour. So the possible interval of how much B is off is `[-2,-0.5]`.

### Challenge

Given a list of timestamps with their labels, return the possible interval by how much B can be off.

### Details

- The list can be in any convenient format like [(timestamp, label),...] or as two lists [timestamp,...],[label,...] e.t.c
- You can assume that all the readings from A are in ascending. (and the same for B)
- If there is no such time interval, output something falsy.

### Testcases:

(more to be added)

```
label  A  B  A
time   1  4  5
output [-1,3]

label  A B B A
time   1 2 5 2.5
output false
```

---

## Meta:

- Should only valid cases be considered, or should there be a check for invalid ones (remove point 2 or 3 of the details?)
- Should the challenge be restricted to alternating readings (`ABABABABABA`) or should random ones be allowed (`ABBAAABABAABBBABBBBB`)? Restricting to alternating readings would make it pretty much trivial.

Comment: IMO go with alternating readings

Comment: @Downgoat But that makes it almost trivial I think...

Comment: _We see that B is at least two hours behind, but at most half an hour behind._ I find that wording confusing. How about this? _We see (`B: 1, A: 3`) that B is behind A by at most 2 hours, and that (`A: 5, B: 4.5`) B is behind A by at least half an hour._

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you, I'm going to correct that.

Answer (score 2):

## Print a booklet

I want to take a PDF document and put four pages of that document onto the front and four pages onto the back of a sheet of paper. Then I'll fold and cut that page so that I end up with a 1/4─size booklet that holds 8 pages. This would produce two *folios* comprising one *signature*.

```
           Fold here
            ↓
       ┌────┬────┐
       │    │    │
       │    │    │ ← Outer folio
Cut    │    │    │
here → ╞════╪════╡
       │    │    │
       │    │    │ ← Inner folio
       │    │    │
       └────┴────┘
```

LaTeX's `pdfpages` package allows me to place 2x2 pages of a PDF per sheet of paper with a given page ordering.

If I were to specify the option `pages={2,7,4,5,8,1,6,3}` to `pdfpages`, I would get:

```
       Front of sheet

        (1)     (8)     Back of sheet
          \     /
        ┌────┬────┐      (7)     (2)
        │    │    │        \     /
Outer   │  2 │  7 │      ┌────┬────┐
folio → │    │    │      │    │    │
        ╞════╪════╡      │  8 │  1 │ ← Outer folio
Inner   │    │    │      │    │    │
folio → │  4 │  5 │      ╞════╪════╡
        │    │    │      │    │    │
        └────┴────┘      │  6 │  3 │ ← Inner folio
        /          \     │    │    │
     (3)            (6)  └────┴────┘
                        /           \
                      (5)            (4)

(Numbers put in parenthesis are referring to the back of the page.)
```

Why do we need that strange order of numbers? So that the fronts and backs of pages line up when put into the signature. This is how you read the book:

```
    Start here at (1) on the back. Continue to 2 on the front.
      │
      │      End here at (8)
      ↓     /
    ┌────┬────┐
    │    │    │
    │  2 │  7 │ ← Outer folio
    │    │    │
    └────┴────┘
      │
On to (3) in
inner folio
      │
      ↓     ↑
          On to (6)
          in outer folio
            │
    ┌────┬────┐
    │    │    │
    │  4 │  5 │ ← Inner folio
    │    │    │
    └────┴────┘
```

But that's just for two folios from one sheet of paper. What if I want to use two sheets of paper, make four folios, and still combine all of them in one signature?

```
            Start at (1)
             │
             │      End here at (16)
             ↓       │
            (1)    (16)  (5)    (12)
              \     /      \     /
            ┌────┬────┐  ┌────┬────┐
            │    │    │  │    │    │
Outermost → │  2 │ 15 │  │  6 │ 11 │ ← Folio #3
 folio (#1) │    │    │  │    │    │
            ╞════╪════╡  ╞════╪════╡
            │    │    │  │    │    │
 Folio #2 → │  4 │ 13 │  │  8 │  9 │ ← Innermost
            │    │    │  │    │    │    folio (#4)      
            └────┴────┘  └────┴────┘
              /     \      /     \
            (3)    (14)  (7)    (10)

            Front of      Front of
             sheet 1       sheet 2
```

And your LaTeX option would be:

```
pages={2,15,4,13,16,1,14,3,6,11,8,9,12,5,10,7}
```

### Objective

Write a function taking an integer `n` of the number of pages in the final booklet (8 and 16 in the examples above) and returning a list integers (of length `n` and ranging from 1 to `n`) for the page numbers in the right order.

Example:

```
> f(8)
=> [2,7,4,5,8,1,6,3]

> f(16)
=> [2,15,4,13,16,1,14,3,6,11,8,9,12,5,10,7]
```

Since we're dividing a sheet of paper into 4 pieces and using front and back, the input is always a multiple of 8. If the input is not a multiple of 8, the output is not defined but would prefer that it's rounded up to the next multiple of 8.

Comment: Is the code required to work for integers that don't fit and leave unused pages? Should such integers be rounded up to the next integer that fits?

Comment: 1. I don't understand the repeated mention of US Letter. Surely this is completely independent of the paper size? 2. I don't understand the first two diagrams. It seems to me that the instructions in the first diagram give a booklet with page order `2,3,4,1`, and the folds in the two diagrams can only be consistent with each other if one of the `1`s is turned upside down. 3. The meaning of *folio* doesn't seem to be consistent between the 4-page example (which has two folios, implying that a folio is a half-sheet of paper) and the 8-page example (which has just an outer and an inner folio).

Comment: I specified what to do with integers that don't fit, removed mention of US letter, and simplified the diagrams.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, the first example is 8 pages (1 physical sheet of paper divided into 2 folios), the second example is 16 pages (2 physical sheets of paper divided into 4 folios). A folio is just a half sheet of paper. I cleaned up the terminology of sheet vs page in the question.

Comment: Ok, I think it's clearer now, but to check that I've understood what the task is. Would the following serve as a reference implementation? Given `n` which is a multiple of 8, form the array `[1 2 ... n-1 n]`. Then while the array is non-empty, remove the first four elements and the last four elements, apply permutation `[2 7 4 5 8 1 6 3]` to them, and recurse on the remaining elements.

Comment: Might turn into something interesting, but if you just print, cut, fold, then sort and glue, there is nothing keeping you from switching upper with lower halfs, turning half-pages around or swapping half-pages between pages. You either need to specify the exact way the paper will be combined or you should add information which solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

## De-Parenthesize Ruby

Reuben wants to start programming and golfing in Ruby. However, since he learned programming from his siblings Cecil and Emma, who program in C and ECMAScript respectively, he's developed a habit of adding parentheses to all sorts of functions when he doesn't need to. However, he can't just remove all the parentheses either! Help him by writing a short program that will remove some of the parentheses for him.

#### The Challenge

Given a snippet of Ruby code (you don't need to worry if it's valid code or not), apply the following rules to remove parentheses from function calls wherever possible. Whenever parentheses are removed, put a whitespace in between the function call and the arguments (even if in actual golfing practice it isn't needed, such as in the case of `print"hello"`)

For the purposes of this challenge, not all parts of Ruby need to be checked:

- Variables/functions will contain alphanumerics and underscore only, and won't start with numbers. (No functions like `array.slice!(1,4).include?(6)`, and no variables like `$a`)
- Blocks (curly braces after functions, or for declaring stabby-lambdas) are not present. No `array.map{|i|i+1}`
- Function definitions like `def f(x)` will not be present.
- No backslashes `\` so you don't have to parse something like `"\"hello\""`
- No comments. (Comments in Ruby start with `#`.) If a `#` appears in code, it's going to be part of a string.

These are the only rules you need to check for:

**Functions without any parameters always have their parens removed.**

```
array.size()+array.something().length() -> array.size+array.something.length
```

**Functions at the end of a method chain can be removed *only if they are not next to an arithmetic operator.***

For the purposes of this challenge, the operators used will be `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`.

```
num.parse(3,7) -> num.parse 3,7
string.gsub("this","that").count("t") -> string.gsub("this","that").count "t"
1+string.count("T") -> 1+string.count("T") # no change
1+(string.count("T")) -> 1+(string.count "T")
puts(3,8*7) -> puts 3,8*7
```

**If a function contains another function call as its *only function argument*, apply the other rules to that function as well.**

```
print(print(x.sub(a,b.to_s(16)))) -> print print x.sub a,b.to_s(16)
```

**If a string substitution operator `#{...}` is present within a string (enclosed with double quotes), remove parens from the functions in accordance to the other rules.**

 Assume that the contents within the string substitution don't include any literal strings, including single-character "question mark" strings like `?a`. This means that things like `"#{"a}#{"}"` or `"#{?}}"` do not need to be dealt with.

```
"hello() #{world().string(5)}" -> "hello() #{world.string 5}"
"hello() # {world()}" -> "hello() # {world()}" # no change
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Might add more rules or other things in the future if people want, before it gets published of course.

Would this be a duplicate of something like [Remove unnecessary parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79436/remove-unnecessary-parentheses)? It's a similar concept but with different rules

Comment: The "only if they are not in an expression with an arithmetic operator" part seems like it might potentially be a problem. What about `1+(string.count("T"))`? Or, how about: `print(foo().bar())+1`? I think you may want to more aggressively remove some of these edge cases.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that's a good point. I will think about how to phrase that case with parentheses to make more sense. For the second example, since the first rule says that empty parens are *always* removed, it'd become `print(foo.bar)+1` as expected anyways.

Comment: I think a whitelist of language constructs would be clearer than listing a lot of things that aren't allowed.

Comment: @feersum I don't understand what you mean by that. Should I say something like "only alphanumerics, the dot operator `.`, these arithmetic operators, and the string substitution operator in strings"?

Comment: Yes, or better some sort of grammar describing the allowed input.

Answer (score 2):

## The Coin Flop KoTH

In this challenge, you start out with a stack of 100 coins, alternating between gold and silver:

```
1.   Gold
2.   Silver
3.   Gold
4.   Silver
     ...
99.  Gold
100. Silver
```

Now, Gold, Inc. will pay you for any gold coins you can give them.  Furthermore, they really like bulk shipment.  If a shipment contains `N` coins, they will pay you `N^2` for that shipment.

However, you've only got 1 truck to share between you and your opponent, who has a similar contract with Silver, Inc.

## Game play

Each turn, the following steps occur:

1. **Flip a section of coins** (like pancakes)
2. **Collect the top coins** (of the same type)
3. **Ship off the collected coins** (worth `N^2`)

### 1. Flip:

You or your opponent can each select a range to reverse.  For example, if you selected the range `[1,3]`, the following would occur:

```
Gold                        Gold
Silver                      Gold
Gold          ->            Gold
Gold                        Silver
Silver                      Silver
```

Notice how the top stack now has 3 golds in a row, which would be worth 9.

However, you only get to flip every other turn, and your opponent gets to flip on the other turns.

## 2. Collect

We collect all similar coins from the top of the stack, and put them in the truck:

```
Silver
Silver
Gold
Silver
Gold
```

Would result in 2 Silvers being put in the truck.

## 3. Ship

If the truck contains gold coins, then we send it off to Gold, Inc and we get paid `N^2`, where `N` is the number of coins in the truck.  (Our opponent gets paid if the truck contains silver coins)

After the stack is empty, the player with the most money wins!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Sandbox questions:

1. Is this clear?
2. Does this seem interesting at all (if it isn't, *please* say so)?  What are some interesting strategies you can come up with?
3. Is there a never-lose strategy?
4. I'm debating adding a "Freeze" as an alternative to "Flip", which would cause *2* collect/ship actions to occur.  (Your opponent's turn would then be next)

Comment: Could you add tags so it's clear this is a KOTH?

Comment: "*If the truck contains gold coins, then we send it off to Gold, Inc (otherwise Silver, Inc), and we get paid*" Is this correct? Earlier you said that we had a contract with Gold, Inc and the opponent with Silver, Inc, so it seems that we should be paid for gold and the opponent for silver.

Comment: @PeterTaylor does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Follow-up: I presume the controller will show different things to the two players so we both think we're the one collecting gold?

Comment: @PeterTaylor correct.  The *only* difference players will notice is whether or not Gold is the first coin.

Answer (score 2):

## Stratego

This is a KOTH challenge based on the popular board game Stratego.

## Rules

Stratego is played on a 10x10 board which looks like this (starting position):

```
  12345678910

A **********
B **********
C **********
D **********
E ..~~..~~..
F ..~~..~~..
G xxxxxxxxxx
H xxxxxxxxxx
I xxxxxxxxxx
J xxxxxxxxxx
```

`*`: enemy piece; `x`: your piece, `.`: empty space, `~`: lake

There are twelve types of pieces: the flag (`F`), the bomb (`B`), the spy (`S`), and pieces numbered 2-10 (ten is `0`). You can see the identities of your pieces, but not your opponent's. Each player starts with:

- 6 bombs
- 1 flag
- 1 ten
- 1 nine
- 2 eights
- 3 sevens
- 4 sixes
- 4 fives
- 4 fours
- 5 threes (miners)
- 8 twos (scouts)
- 1 spy

A player may arrange their pieces however they wish within their starting area.

The players take turns moving one piece into an adjacent square.

- The bomb and flag may not move.
- Twos (scouts) may move any number of squares in one direction, like a chess rook.
- You may not move into a square containing one of your pieces.
- If you attempt to move into a piece containing an enemy piece:

  - The identities of both pieces are revealed to the other player.
  - If both pieces are equal, they both lose.
  - If both pieces are numbered, the higher piece wins.
  - If the attacked piece is a bomb…

    - and the other piece is a miner, the miner wins.
    - otherwise, the bomb wins.
  - If the attacked piece is the flag, then the player owning the flag loses.
  - If the attacking piece is the spy…

    - and the defending piece is a 10, the spy wins.
    - otherwise, the spy loses.
  - If the attacked piece is the spy, it loses.
  - If the attacking piece won, the attacked piece is removed from the board and the attacking piece moves into its place.
  - If the attacked piece won, the attacking piece is removed from the board and the attacked piece remains in place.
  - If both pieces lose, they are both removed from the board.
- A scout's move may end on an enemy piece, but it may not go *over* enemy pieces during its move.

Play continues until one player loses their flag or is unable to move on their turn, at which point that player loses.

## Protocol

Bots may be written in any language that I can get to run on macOS. They will communicate with the server using newline-separated JSON on stdin/stdout. When a bot is started, it should send the following message:

```
{
  "type": "start",
  "layout": "..." /* starting layout, as 4x10 string; last line is edge of board */
}
```

When it is the bot's turn, the server will send the following message:

```
{
  "type": "turn",
  "board": "...", /* current board state, as 10x10 string; you half of the board is always on the bottom */
  "yourPreviousTurn": { /* result of your previous turn; not present on your first turn */
    "from": "B8",
    "to": "B9", /* you moved a piece from B8 to B9 */
    "movedPiece": "5" /* you moved a 5 */
    "attackedPiece": "8" /* the piece you attacked was an 8; only present if you attacked a piece on your last turn */,
    "winner": "them" /* their piece won; only present if you attacked a piece */
  },
  "theirPreviousTurn": { /* result of the turn they just took; not present on first turn of the game */
    "from": "H8",
    "to": "G8",
    "movedPiece": "4" /* they moved a 4; only present if they attacked */
    "attackedPiece": "9" /* they attacked your 9; only present if they attacked */,
    "winner": "you" /* your piece won; only present if they attacked */
  },
  "yourGraveyard": ["B", "3", ...], /* array of your pieces that have already died */
  "theirGraveyard": ["7", "4", ...] /* array of their pieces that have already died */
}
```

You must respond with:

```
{
  "type": "move",
  "from": "A6",
  "to": "A7"
}
```

## Answering

Submit your bot as a pull request to [github link added here]. You do not need to include your entire bot in the SE answer, but please include the main/interesting parts of the code; I would recommend *not* including the layouts that you are using so that they remain secret (not *that* secret, but better than nothing). I will run bots regularly and post the latest scores here.

Comment: 1. Can you give references to indicate that there is no legal issue here (with respect to copyright, trademarks, etc)? 2. Why `2` to `9` and then `0`? Would it be simpler to use `1` to `9`? 3. The list of starting pieces could be presented much more succinctly as a single string (`BBBBBBF9...`), and the combat table as a grid with columns and rows headed by `B`, `F`, etc and using one of three symbols to indicate the outcome. 4. Docker images? Are you serious? You should be trying to lower the barrier of entry, not raise it.

Comment: This is a dupe of my stratego challenge....

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9653/46918

Comment: 1. I feel that the copyright on the game is unlikely to be enforced for something this small. 2. The original game uses 2-10, so I am staying with that. 3. That would be more succinct, but less useful for understanding the game -- it would be nice not to have to analyze a table to understand things like "larger number wins." 4. Agreed. I will edit to remove the Docker requirement.

Comment: @Peter see above

Comment: Whether the copyright holder decides to take action or not is irrelevant: if posting this challenge would violate copyright then this site's [legal terms](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#3SubscriberContent) prohibit it. (CC @RohanJhunjhunwala).

Comment: @PeterTaylor game rules can not be copyrighted: http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl108.pdf

Comment: @PeterTaylor from what I understand, developing an AI to play a game isn't really breaching the copyright of the game holder. However I feel we should take this to meta.

Comment: @PeterTaylor feel free to continue to discuss this here http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9925/46918

Comment: Gaelan, the document you link states that game rules *are* subject to copyright: it's the *mechanics* which aren't. The design elements probably extend to such matters as board layout and tile distribution: or, at least, the major Scrabble clones' owners weren't confident enough of winning against Hasbro, and changed their layouts and distributions under legal pressure. And I (and the SE legal terms) also mentioned trademarks: [Stratego](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4809:4wg2u0.2.12) is a registered trademark in the US.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala, the AI might not be, but a [tag:king-of-the-hill] doesn't work without a controller.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I will rename the challenge to avoid the trademark issue. Nothing in the PDF says anything about *rules* being copyrighted. It says the specific *wording* of the rules that came with the game are copyrightable, but I wrote the rules in my own words from memory. Also, see the dupe link in the meta question.

Comment: @Gaelan you have failed to address the issue that it is a dupe of my challenge

Comment: @PeterTaylor sure I can edit the name of my challenge to avoid stomping on a trademark. (But from what I understand you can saw the name of a company, without infringing their trademarks)

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala sorry, I didn't realize your challenge was this recent. Are you still planning on running your challenge?

Comment: @Gaelan yes I do plan to run it in the forseeable future

Comment: However there is a good chance that I do abandon it, if I do abandon it feel free to contact me again.

Answer (score 2):

## Shift and Sum

(I need a better title)

Write a program or function that given an input list of non-negative integers of length `l`, outputs the sum of all the lists of length `2*l-1` that are the input list padded with `0`s to each side.

(Please suggest ways of improving this description)

For example, with the input `[1,2,3]`:

```
[1,2,3,0,0]+
[0,1,2,3,0]+
[0,0,1,2,3]=
[1,3,6,5,3]
```

More test cases:

```
[1]->[1]
[2,1]->[2,3,1]
[1,0,1]->[1,1,2,1,1]
[0,1,0]->[0,1,1,1,0]
[10,20,30]->[10,30,60,50,30]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]->[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

You may take input in any reasonable format. If you have any questions about whether an input form is reasonable, ask about it in the comments.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: In other words, convolution [inserts dup]

Comment: Do all the inputs consist of lists of integers 0-9, or can they be greater/negative?

Comment: @Theo I was thinking they would be lists of non-negative integers. I will clarify that.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80030/194

Answer (score 2):

## End the tabs versus space war

So, there has been a great deal of debate of whether to use tabs or spaces to indent/format code. Can you help the university settle the dispute, by going to an incredibly <s>crazy</s> unique method of formatting.

---

Your job is to write a full program or function which expands all tabs into four spaces. And then replaces a run of n leading spaces with "/(n-2 *'s)/". You will receive input over multiple lines in any reasonable format (single string array of strings for each new line. Columnar array etc.)

---

Sample input [shamelessly stolen](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Note that tabs get automagically expanded to four spaces on SE, but you must handle tabs as well.

```
Calculate the value 256 and test if it's zero
If the interpreter errors on overflow this is where it'll happen
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>[<++++>-]
+<[>-<
    Not zero so multiply by 256 again to get 65536
    [>++++<-]>[<++++++++>-]<[>++++++++<-]
    +>[>
        # Print "32"
        ++++++++++[>+++++<-]>+.-.[-]<
    <[-]<->] <[>>
        # Print "16"
        +++++++[>+++++++<-]>.+++++.[-]<
<<-]] >[>
    # Print "8"
    ++++++++[>+++++++<-]>.[-]<
<-]<
# Print " bit cells\n"
+++++++++++[>+++>+++++++++>+++++++++>+<<<<-]>-.>-.+++++++.+++++++++++.<.
>>.++.+++++++..<-.>>-
Clean up used cells.
[[-]<]l
    this is preceded by a tab
        two tabs
            three tabs etcetera!
```

Sample output

```
Calculate the value 256 and test if it's zero
If the interpreter errors on overflow this is where it'll happen
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>[<++++>-]
+<[>-<
/**/Not zero so multiply by 256 again to get 65536
/**/[>++++<-]>[<++++++++>-]<[>++++++++<-]
/**/+>[>
/******/# Print "32"
/******/++++++++++[>+++++<-]>+.-.[-]<
/**/<[-]<->] <[>>
/******/# Print "16"
/******/+++++++[>+++++++<-]>.+++++.[-]<
<<-]] >[>
/**/# Print "8"
/**/++++++++[>+++++++<-]>.[-]<
<-]<
# Print " bit cells\n"
+++++++++++[>+++>+++++++++>+++++++++>+<<<<-]>-.>-.+++++++.+++++++++++.<.
>>.++.+++++++..<-.>>-
Clean up used cells.
[[-]<]l
/**/this is preceded by a tab
/******/two tabs
/**********/three tabs etcetera!
```

---

Because the university needs space to download both Vim and Emacs. You are alloted very little storage for your code. Therefore this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and the shortest code wins.

#### Disclaimer

This "excellent" formatting strategy came courtesy of Geobits, and is reproduced with his permission. No programmers were harmed during the production of this challenge.

Comment: Disclaimer: By using this formatting, you hereby absolve Geobits of any liability for any injuries (intentional or otherwise) or damages you may receive as a result. Void where prohibited.

Comment: Also, do only *leading* spaces/tabs get replaced?

Comment: What does "*expands all tabs into four space**" mean? Is it a straight replacement à la http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57462/194 or does it mean expanding to tab stops every 4 chars à la http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18960/194 ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor essentially line.repaceAll("\t","    ");

Comment: So all tabs get replaced by spaces, and then only leading spaces get replaced by "comments"?

Comment: @Geobits yes that is a very clear way of putting it.

Comment: this is genius, I should start using it.

Comment: You should delete this. now that it's been posted.

Answer (score 2):

### What is my birthday?

In the system of surreal numbers, every number has a birthday, which is used to resolve ties in the case of there being more than one surreal number that would otherwise satisfy an equation.

The very first surreal number to be created is zero, written as `{|}`. Its birthday is therefore zero. Having created zero, the next two surreal numbers to be created are 1 and -1. Their birthdays are therefore both 1.

Each subsequent day brings in twice as many surreal numbers as the previous day: 2ⁿ-2 numbers are obtained by taking the averages of all the consecutive pairs from all previous days, with the first and last numbers simply incrementing in absolute value. For example, on the second day, the previous surreal numbers are -1, 0 and 1, giving averages of -½ and ½, to which we also add -2 and 2, whilst on the third day the new numbers are -3, -1½, -¾, -¼, ¼, ¾, 1½ and 3.

As you can see, all finite floating-point representations have a finite birthday. (Most real numbers have an infinite binary fraction and therefore an infinite birthday). Your task is to write a program or function that outputs the birthday for a given floating-point number (using your native floating-point format). Although the birthday is always an integer, you can return it as an integer valued floating-point number if you prefer (e.g. if you don't have an unlimited integer type). Test cases:

```
Number  Birthday
  1        1
  0.5      2
-21       21
  6.5      8
 -7.9375  12
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins.

Comment: Could you perhaps please add how the number generation process works?

Comment: @Sp3000 The line beginning "In general" was supposed to explain that, although there was some spurious text on it that you may have found confusing.

Comment: Hmm right, I see. Sorry it took me a while to get what it meant - maybe a quick example, e.g. saying the third day takes averages from 2, 1, ½, 0, -½, -1, -2? (to drive home the "all previous birthdays" part). But otherwise I think this looks pretty good.

Comment: Maybe you should give more examples from Knuth because, for instance, from your current explanation it is unclear why 1/3 should have a birthday of ω: it is not a finite sum of dyadic rationals. Or better give example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Consider adding these test cases: `Input: 1, 0.5, -21, 6.5, -7.9375` and `Output: 1, 2, 21, 8, 12`.

Answer (score 2):

### Table Math

You should which side of a table is the oldest, from ASCII art. I think the best way to explain is with an example, so here is one.

You have a table, made out of `+`, `|`, and `-`. Here is one.

```
+--+
|  |
|  |
|  |
+--+
```

It will alway be a rectangle, just not always square (but it can be square). There will also be people around the table, marked by the letters A-Z. There will never be too many people on a side, or less than one. Just to make it harder, the people will not always be in order, like this:

```
  P
 +--+
I|  |
O|  |Q
 |  |J
 +--+
   U
```

There will never be anybody next to a plus sign(`+`). You will be given input on how old each member is, separated by a newline, from the first letter that appears alphabetically (I in this example) to the last letter that appears alphabetically (U in this example), like this:

```
20
8
31
56
6
56
```

As seen here, ties are allowed. You should then output the sides with their ages separated with a space, in order from oldest to youngest, like this.

```
Top 56
Bottom 56
Left 51
Right 14
```

Note that for everything in this challenge, you can choose the capitalization of the letters, even the input. The winner is the submission with the shortest code.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Answer (score 2):

### Show the Key Signature

Here is are the key signatures for the key of C♯ Major in the treble clef, and C♭ major in the bass clef:

```
           ♯
─────♯───────────────────────   ─────────────────────────────
                    ♯
──────────────♯──────────────   ─────────────────────────────
        ♯                               ♭
───────────────────────♯─────   ──────────────♭──────────────
                 ♯                                  ♭
─────────────────────────────   ─────♭───────────────────────
                                           ♭
─────────────────────────────   ─────────────────♭───────────
                                                       ♭
```

A full list of key signatures can be found [here](https://blog.key-notes.com/key-signature-chart.html). Hopefully you will notice that a) the sharps and flats are two notes lower in the bass clef as compared to the treble clef b) all key signatures can be obtained from the C♯ Major and C♭ Major key signatures by removing trailing sharps and flats appropriately.

Your task is, given a suitable representation of the clef and key, to output the appropriate key signature using the above format.

- Your output must have at least 11 lines, in order to accommodate all possible placings of sharps and flats.
- To compensate for the terrible aspect ratio, each sharp and flat must be separated by two columns, and there must be at least five empty columns at the beginning and end, but no more than 29 columns in total.
- You may use #, b and - characters instead of ♯, ♭ and ─.

This is [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins!

Comment: Can I adopt this abandoned challenge?

Comment: @programmer5000 Sorry, I'm not very good at checking back to see how my Sandbox posts are doing. As I don't have many questions myself, I'd rather be the person to ask it, if you don't mind. (But feel free to comment on any changes you think I should make first.)

Comment: Ok sure. I think it is ready to post.

Comment: @programmer5000 Oh, I meant to ask, what input format do you think I should accept for the clef and key? Representing the key as a number between -7 and 7 feels like cheating to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Handwriting Recognition

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

I made a similar suggestion a month or so back which was deemed to be too similar to an existing one, so I've added something along the lines of a kolmogorov-complexity requirement.

---

[The MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is a series of handwritten digits used as a standard testbed for machine learning, pattern recognition techniques. Each image is of a single digit, `0-9`; as a `28x28` pixel grayscale matrix with values from `0-255`.

[image: MNIST example images]

The challenge is to create a classifier for MNIST that scores an Error Rate of less than `[TBD]` in the least number of bytes possible.

Your program must take a `784` element long array in whatever format is applicable for your language representing a single image and return a number between 0 and 9, guessing what the number is.

For example, the input for the first digit might be:

```
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3, 18, 18, 18,126,136,175, 26,166,255,247,127,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 30, 36, 94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251, 93, 82, 82, 56, 39,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 80,156,107,253,253,205, 11,  0, 43,154,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  1,154,253, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,139,253,190,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,190,253, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 35,241,225,160,108,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 81,240,253,253,119, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 45,186,253,253,150, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 93,252,253,187,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,249,253,249, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 46,130,183,253,253,207,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201, 78,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 23, 66,213,253,253,253,253,198, 81,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195, 80,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0, 55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132, 16,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
```

Each algorithm will be tested over a set of 200 images and are expected to get `[TBD]/200` correct.

Of course, when developing any good classifier, you need to test how well it works with a completely unknown sample. The twist of the challenge, these are the 200 images I am going to test with right here: (a link to 200 images and their correct labels). You only need to make sure you can classify at least `[TBD]/200` of these, your algorithm won't be run on anything else. As such, this can be considered a kolmogorov complexity challenge with an acceptable error rate.

### Conditions:

- This is code golf. The shortest piece of code that meets the criteria wins.
- The code must take a provided `784` element long input and attempt to classify it.
- Testing will take place on my computer at 12pm AEST on Saturday the (date two weeks after the competition is published). I will run each classifier over the published set of 200 images. To be considered, it must correctly classify `[TBD]/200` of them. If I can't get your code to run, it wont be counted, so help with loading the images in your language would be appreciated.
- Standard loopholes are not permitted.

## Questions for Sandbox

- Overall thoughts on the challenge?
- Any ideas on a good cutoff for the classifier? I was thinking around 60% correct. Very low when compared to existing solutions to MNIST, but should promote good code golfing. I was going to have a go at it myself to see what I could reasonably achieve.
- Does the testing clause make sense? Is it reasonable? Should I put a limit on the languages so I know I'll be able to run them?
- Since barrier to entry is a bit high (knowing how to get hold of the images, possibly some ML experience), is there anything extra I should do to make it easier to start the challenge.
- This is a modification of my first suggestion for a challenge, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I recommend a time limit, especially if you intend to test them yourself. It can be generous, but without one then the requirement to golf will naturally give very long run times which you may not wish to commit your computer to...

Comment: Do submissions need to be deterministic? That is, should the results be identical each run?

Comment: For choosing the maximum error rate, think about what kinds of approaches you want to see. For a sufficiently high error rate, it may be possible to look only at a small number of pixels and ignore most of the image. If you want this kind of approach, try to choose an error rate that makes it challenging but possible. If you prefer more complex approaches, the error rate will need to be set a little lower.

Answer (score 2):

## Monopoly Continued

So [you've got your Monopoly board](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102423/15394), shall we start a game?

To start with, we'll need some dice and to know where we land!

Write a program that outputs the rolls and resting places of a given number players for a given number turns.

### Input

*In any suitable format for your language*

- The number of players up to a maximum of 6
- The number of turns to output up to a maximum of 250

### Output

*In any meaningful option for your chosen language*

- The output should be in the format: `PlayerNumber, Die1, Die2, InitialOfRestingPlace`
- Each roll should be separated by a new line.

---

### Rules

### General

- Use the US Board for the names of squares

```
    F K C I I B A V W M G 
    N                   P
    T                   N
    C                   C
    S                   P
    P                   S
    V                   C
    S                   P
    E                   L
    S                   B
    J C V C O R I B C M G
```

- All players start on Go (bottom right)
- A player rolls (pseudo randomly generated) two six-sided dice, once per turn, unless they roll doubles (described below), and moves that many spaces clockwise.

### Doubles

- Rolling doubles means the player can roll again
- Rolling three doubles in a row lands the player in jail and the players turn ends

### Jail

- Landing on the "Go To Jail" square sends the player to jail
- While in jail, the player may not move unless they roll a double
- Rolling a double to get out of jail ends the player's turn
- Landing **on** the jail square does not mean a player is **in** jail

### Chance/Community Chest

- These squares currently have no effect.

---

### Example output

*Excluding comments*

For input 2,3

```
//Turn 1
1,2,2,I   //Player lands on Income Tax, Player rolled doubles, roll again
1,2,4,J   //Player lands on Jail and turn ends
2,5,3,V   //Player lands on Vermont Avenue and turn ends

//Turn 2
1,5,5,F   //Player lands on Free Parking, doubles, roll again.
1,5,5,G   //Player lands on Go To Jail, goes to Jail, turn ends
2,3,4,P   //Player lands on Pennsylvania Railroad, and the turn ends.

//Turn 3
1,5,2,J   //No double, player remains in Jail
2,6,3,I   //Player lands on Illinois Avenue and turn ends.
```

---

### Scoring

<strike>This didn't start as a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, but in coming up with scoring, a lot of the elements I thought of for scoring were very "golf-y" by nature, so I've changed my mind (before any answers are posted). See the edit history if the previous scoring intrigues you.</strike>

---

Despite first posting this on the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10343/15394), I'm bound to have missed something! Please feel free to point out mistakes or problems.

---

## Concerns

- <strike>Too complex</strike>
- **How to score?**
- <strike>Doesn't include Chance or Community Chest cards</strike>

Comment: I am actually coding monopoly right now which is how I got the idea for the code golf, the movement isn't the most complex thing in the world but the buying and building houses etc is very much so. 

I am not sure if you will get many takers if it is code-gold, maybe a code-challenge?

Comment: This isn't too complex.  However, it *is* tough to make test cases, as the game is non-deterministic, and testing for edge cases (I landed on Jail, but I'm not *in* Jail) is tough for the reader to do.  I'd still include the Monopoly board this time around.

Comment: Incomplete. What about chance / community chest cards which send the player to a different square?

Comment: @NathanMerrill, do you propose any changes? Or just pointing out a risk?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I did intentionally leave out chance and community chest to reduce complexity

Comment: @jacksonecac I'm all for code challenge, but I'm unsure how the scoring would work

Comment: Scoring could be by popularity contest.

Comment: Popularity contest is a terrible idea. Code golf would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

## Classify Alternating Permutations

An alternating permutation of `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]` is an arrangement such that each element is either greater than its previous and greater than the next, meaning `p[i-1] < p[i] > p[i+1]` or lesser than the previous and lesser than the next, meaning `p[i-1] > p[i] < p[i+1]`. In other words, this means that each run of three consecutive elements should never be strictly increasing or decreasing. There is a further distinction that an alternating permutation can be either *UP* or *DOWN*. For *UP*, this means that the alternating permutation begins with the first element being less than the second, and the opposite is true for *DOWN*. For example, there are 4! = 24 permutations of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4  Alternating UP since 1 < 3 > 2 < 4
1 3 4 2
1 4 2 3  Alternating UP since 1 < 4 > 2 < 3
1 4 3 2
2 1 3 4
2 1 4 3  Alternating DOWN since 2 > 1 < 4 > 3
2 3 1 4  Alternating UP since 2 < 3 > 1 < 4
2 3 4 1
2 4 1 3  Alternating UP since 2 < 4 > 1 < 3
2 4 3 1
3 1 2 4
3 1 4 2  Alternating DOWN since 3 > 1 < 4 > 2
3 2 1 4
3 2 4 1  Alternating DOWN since 3 > 2 < 4 > 1
3 4 1 2  Alternating UP since 3 < 4 > 1 < 3
3 4 2 1
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2  Alternating DOWN since 4 > 1 < 3 > 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1  Alternating DOWN since 4 > 2 < 3 > 1
4 3 1 2
4 3 2 1
```

The permutations left unmarked are *NOT* alternating.

Your goal is take a permutation and output whether it is

- alternating *UP*
- *NOT* alternating
- alternating *DOWN*

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- You are allowed to modify the input be 0-indexed, 1-indexed, or a permutation of the English alphabet `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in uppercase or lowercase.
- The length of the input will be between 2 and 26.
- You are allowed to choose your own output to represent the three classes but you must state what they are in your submission.

### Test Cases

```
1 2  UP
2 1  DOWN
1 2 3  NOT
1 3 2  UP
2 1 3  DOWN
2 3 1  UP
3 1 2  DOWN
3 2 1  NOT
<more to be added...>
```

Comment: The phrase "each element is greater than or less than the previous element" is not very clear (arguably, it just means that consecutive elements are distinct, which always holds in a permutation). I suggest something like "doesn't contain an increasing or decreasing run of three consecutive numbers", and then you can clarify that the permutation alternates between rising and falling pairs.

Comment: @Zgarb I've tried to clarify the definition a bit more

Comment: Isn't *"each element is either greater than its previous and lesser than the next or lesser than the previous and greater than the next"* the exact opposite of what an alternating permutation is? It should be either greater than both the previous and the next, or lesser than both.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks, I got it backwards.

Comment: Can I adopt this abandoned proposal?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: this is an attempt to fix up a [currently closed question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96810/194) by someone else so that they can rescue it, not an attempt to steal their question.

When implementing an algorithm for correcting [aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) measurement data, I hit the need to implement following function. The function takes input bitstring on the left, and should produce the integer and list on the right:

```
               1 =>   1, [0]
              10 =>   1, [0]
             100 =>   1, [0]
             101 =>   2, [0, 1]
            1000 =>   1, [0]
            1011 =>   3, [0, 2, 1]
     ... more test cases at end of post ...
```

Note that it is guaranteed that the input bitstring is aperiodic.

### Physical background

Consider a digital system that changes its output every `N` clock cycles. A measurement system doesn't know `N`, so it reads the output every `M` cycles, where `M <= N`.

Now some of the measurement samples will be identical to the previous ones, which is represented as `0` in the bitstring and the sample is discarded. When the value changes, `1` is added to the bitstring and the sample is stored.

However, the timestamp of the sample will be too late. The numbers in the output array represent a correction that must be applied. The output format expresses this correction as a fraction of the sample interval, where the standalone integer is the denominator and the array contains the numerators.

As an example with `N = 4` and `M = 3`:

```
Clock cycle     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Output          A A A A B B B B C C C C D D D D E E E E
Measurement     A     A     B     C     D     D     E
Bitstring       1     0     1     1     1     0     1
                |---------------------| This is the period of the aliasing

Timestamp       |       |---|   |-|     |       |---|
  correction    0          2/3   1/3    0          2/3
```

With this example the input would be `1011` and the output would be `3, [0, 2, 1]`.

### Here are a few observations to get you started:

- The input sequence always begins with `1` and is aperiodic.
- The output sequence length always equals the number of 1-bits in the input.
- The output sequence array is always a permutation of `0` to `M-1` and begins with `0`.

### Test cases:

```
               1 =>   1, [0]
              10 =>   1, [0]
             100 =>   1, [0]
             101 =>   2, [0, 1]
            1000 =>   1, [0]
            1011 =>   3, [0, 2, 1]
           10000 =>   1, [0]
           10010 =>   2, [0, 1]
           10101 =>   3, [0, 1, 2]
           10111 =>   4, [0, 3, 2, 1]
          100000 =>   1, [0]
          101111 =>   5, [0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
         1000000 =>   1, [0]
         1000100 =>   2, [0, 1]
         1001010 =>   3, [0, 2, 1]
         1010101 =>   4, [0, 1, 2, 3]
         1011011 =>   5, [0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
         1011111 =>   6, [0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
        10000000 =>   1, [0]
        10010010 =>   3, [0, 1, 2]
        10101101 =>   5, [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
        10111111 =>   7, [0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
       100000000 =>   1, [0]
       100001000 =>   2, [0, 1]
       100101010 =>   4, [0, 3, 2, 1]
       101010101 =>   5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
       101110111 =>   7, [0, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2]
       101111111 =>   8, [0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
      1000000000 =>   1, [0]
      1000100100 =>   3, [0, 2, 1]
      1011011011 =>   7, [0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]
      1011111111 =>   9, [0, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
     10000000000 =>   1, [0]
     10000010000 =>   2, [0, 1]
     10001000100 =>   3, [0, 1, 2]
     10010010010 =>   4, [0, 1, 2, 3]
     10010101010 =>   5, [0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
     10101010101 =>   6, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     10101101101 =>   7, [0, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4]
     10110111011 =>   8, [0, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3]
     10111101111 =>   9, [0, 7, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2]
     10111111111 =>  10, [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    100101001010 =>   5, [0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
    101010110101 =>   7, [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
    101111111111 =>  11, [0, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    111111111111 =>  13, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
   1000000100000 =>   2, [0, 1]
   1000010001000 =>   3, [0, 2, 1]
   1000100100100 =>   4, [0, 3, 2, 1]
   1001001010010 =>   5, [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
   1001010101010 =>   6, [0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
   1010101010101 =>   7, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   1010110101101 =>   8, [0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5]
   1011011011011 =>   9, [0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
   1011101110111 =>  10, [0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3]
   1011111011111 =>  11, [0, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
   1011111111111 =>  12, [0, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  10000100001000 =>   3, [0, 1, 2]
  10010010010010 =>   5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  10101101101101 =>   9, [0, 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5]
  10111011110111 =>  11, [0, 8, 5, 2, 10, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3]
  10111111111111 =>  13, [0, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 100000001000000 =>   2, [0, 1]
 100010001000100 =>   4, [0, 1, 2, 3]
 100101010101010 =>   7, [0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 101010101010101 =>   8, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 101101110111011 =>  11, [0, 7, 3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 8, 4]
 101111110111111 =>  13, [0, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
 101111111111111 =>  14, [0, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Answer (score 2):

## Finding isomorphic elementary cellular automata

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)

An [elementary cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton) is a one-dimensional cellular automaton with two possible states (labeled 0 and 1) and calculates the following state based on a cell and its two immediate neighbors. Each elementary cellular automaton has a rule attached to it that specifies the resulting state for each of the configurations of a cell and its immediate neighbors.

The most common scheme for numbering these rules being the [Wolfram code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_code), where we assign each rule a number from 0 to 255 which has become standard. Each possible current configuration is written in order, 111, 110, ..., 001, 000, and the resulting state for each of these configurations is written in the same order and interpreted as the binary representation of an integer. This number is taken to be the rule number of the automaton.

As an example, we look at [rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110):

```
Cell configuration  111  110  101  100  011  010  001  000
Resulting state      0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0
```

Converting `01101110` back to decimal gives us 110.

Not all rules are equal, of course. Of the 256 possible rules, many of these rules are trivially equivalent to each other up to a simple transformation of the underlying geometry. Each rule will have three isomorphic rules based on three transformations, though sometimes a rule will be isomorphic to itself under a particular transformation.

The first such transformation is reflection through a vertical axis and the result of applying this transformation to a given rule is called the **mirrored rule**. These rules will exhibit the same behavior up to reflection through a vertical axis, and so are equivalent in a computational sense.

For example, if the definition of rule 110 is reflected through a vertical line, the following rule (rule 124) is obtained:

```
Cell configuration  111  110  101  100  011  010  001  000
Resulting state      0    1    1    1    1    1    0    0
```

We swap only those cell configurations that are different when reflected through a vertical axis. The result of 110 is swapped with the result of 011, and the result of 100 is swapped with the result of 001. Everything else remains in place, as they are symmetrical.

The second such transformation is to exchange the roles of 0 and 1 in the definition. The result of applying this transformation to a given rule is called the **complementary rule**. For example, if this transformation is applied to rule 110, we get the following rule:

```
Cell configuration  000  001  010  011  100  101  110  111
Resulting state      1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
```

and, after reordering, we discover that this is rule 137:

```
Cell configuration  111  110  101  100  011  010  001  000
Resulting state      1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

Finally, the previous two transformations can be applied successively to a rule to obtain the **mirrored complementary rule**. For example, the mirrored complementary rule of rule 110 is rule 193.

Of the 256 elementary cellular automata, there are 88 which are inequivalent under these transformations.

**The challenge**

- Your task is given an input rule number, determine which elementary cellular automata are isomorphic under these rules.
- The output should be a list (or equivalent) that represents:

  - The smallest Wolfram rule that is isomorphic to the input,
  - Its mirrored rule,
  - Its complementary rule, and
  - Its mirrored complementary rule.
- The output list may be reordered, though it should always be clear which rule is the smallest, the mirrored rule, and so on. Just sorting the list will not help here.
- This is code golf. Smallest number of bytes wins.

As always, if this challenge needs clarification or correction, let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

**Test cases**

All of the following test cases have the format `[smallest, mirrored, complementary, mirrored complementary]`:

```
110
[110, 124, 137, 193]

232
[232, 232, 232, 232]

0
[0, 0, 255, 255]

16
[2, 16, 191, 247]

42
[42, 112, 171, 241]

144
[130, 144, 190, 246]
```

## Sandbox questions

- Can the specification be clearer or shorter?
- Should I change this challenge from code golf to some other scoring system?
- Should the input be different and challenge changed? If so, which of the following input systems should it be:

  - The input that is currently used: a single rule number, and the challenge is changed to only finding the isomorphisms.
  - The number of states of the automaton, where finding the complementary rules would be more complex (for 2 states, only two possible complements; for 3 states, six complements are possible). This would extend the definition of both the Wolfram code and the cellular automata.
  - Any other suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a kind of [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge, considering the fixed output?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Nuts, you're right. Well, as the "Sandbox questions" section asks, what should the input be, in your opinion?

Comment: Perhaps you could input a rule number, and the program should find the smallest isomorphic rule and then output its four-element list.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Seems reasonable. I'd still like a challenge where you have to find the four-element list for all combinations, but perhaps that can be a sequel. I'll edit the challenge.

Comment: Surely reflection through a vertical axis is reflection horizontally, not vertically?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks! Any other corrections or suggestions?

Comment: That was the only thing I noticed.

Answer (score 2):

> This message is open for anyone to adopt and post to main. For more details, see the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption) or [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792/58826).

## Visualized Tree of 3n+1 Conjecture

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Originally by [@KeyuGan](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59292/keyu-gan). Thanks for letting me use this!

### Introduction

Probably you are already familiar with 3n+1 conjecture (aka Collatz conjecture). As is stated in [this golfing problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture):

- Start with an integer *n* > 1.
- Repeat the following steps:

  - If *n* is even, divide it by 2.
  - If *n* is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1.

And it is proven that for all positive integers up to *5 * 2<sup>60</sup>*, or about *5764000000000000000*, *n* will eventually reach *1*.

It is easy to draw a chain of the whole process for an integer (e.g. for 5, the chain is `1<-2<-4<-8<-16<-5`).

### Task Description

You are asked to print a string of a visualized 3n+1 tree of all chains resulting from positive integers from 2 to `n`, containing new lines if necessary.

### Input and Output

There is only one input `n`, which can be read from stdin, be a function parameter or from any external sources.

You can safely assume input is valid and does not exceed your language's processing ability. However, your code should be able to deal with inputs of `2` - `446`. Under such circumstances, the biggest number involved is `13120`.

[**Sandbox note:** Is `446` a proper minimum ? It turns out to be the largest number in which the biggest number involves is less than `32767`]

The output is flexible, as long as:

- It is a textfile, or a string, or an array of characters, or an array of lines.
- It contains only `0`-`9`, `-`, `|`, `<`, `>`, `^`, `v`, spaces or new lines, where `<`, `>`, `^`, `v` are for arrows, `-`, `|` are for lines.
- Not hardcoded
- Correctly visualized and in proper directions (for instance, `1->2->4->8->16->5` and `1-2-4-8-16-5` are not accepted.)
- All numbers included in the output occur exactly once.
- All leaves of the visualized tree should lie in the range of 2 ~ `n`, that is, all numbers in the output must be necessary for the result.
- the destination of every chain is 1

Besides, the output should meet the following formatting criterion:

- A number should be arranged horizontally and connected.
- There should not be horizontally-adjancent digits from different numbers. For instance, in the following example, `17<34 23<46` is OK, while `17<3423<46` is not. Space(s) should be put between the two numbers under this circumstance.
- There should not be vertically-adjancent digits as well.
- There should not be zero(es) before a number (such as `0016`).
- There should be only one arrow for a line.
- The line between two numbers must be straight.
- As is demonstrated in output, `-` and `|` can be omitted if not neccessary.
- Lines should not be crossed. A solution without crossed lines is proved to be available. A simple explaination is: Thinking in reverse, you can start from integer `x`, and draw `2x` and `(x-1)/3` (if result is odd) following `x`, and repeat the process for every new number. Stop when you have all required integers from 2 ~ `n` in the graph and erase all unneccessary numbers.
- You can only draw a line onto and from a number directly, that is, the arrow of the line must be pointing at a digit. e.g. `|<--`, `^<--`, `|--` and `^--` are not accepted.
- The direction of arrows and lines must be correct. e.g. `^-` and `<|` are not accepted.
- There should not be spaces between arrow and number.
- There should not be spaces between arrows and lines, neither in lines.

[**Sandbox note:** Tell me plz if you come up with other loopholes.]

Output is assumed to be printed in a monospaced font (all characters have same width).

### Sample

Input

```
15
```

Possible Output 1

```
1<2<4<8<16
         ^
         5<10<20<40<80<160
           ^     ^     ^
           3<6<12|     53<106
                 |        ^
                 13<26<52 35<70
                       ^     ^
                       17<34 23<46
                          ^     ^
                          11<22 15
                             ^
                             7<14<28
                                  ^
                                  9
```

Possible Output 2

```
                   15
                   v
                   46
                   v
                   23
                   v
                   70
                   v
                   35
                   v
                   106
                   v
                   53
                   v
                   160
                   v
                   80
                   v
1<2<4<8<16<5<10<20<40<13<26<52<17<34<11<22<7<14<28<9
             ^
             3
             ^
             6
             ^
             12
```

Possible Output 3

```
1<2<4<8<16<5     80<160<53<106<35<70<23<46<15
           ^     v
    12>6>3>10<20<40<13<26<52<17<34<11<22<7<14<28<9
```

### Scoring

Your answer should include verifiable output of input `42`, without a violation to output requirements. And you should verify your answers with different answers on this page: *TBD*

[**Sandbox note:** I will provide a js checker on my site to validate an output.]

Among all accepted codes, shortest code wins.

Comment: Smallest output can be a useful winning criterion in some cases, where there is the possibility of continuously finding smaller outputs with little chance of finding an optimal solution. However, in this case the sequence will always be the same, so the winning criterion is how short an output format can be made before being judged unreadable. This has two problems: 1. This will force output formats towards the subjective boundary between readable and unreadable, making judging validity difficult. 2. An output format does not require programming skill.

Comment: You might want to consider taking out the "readable" requirement and just keeping the objective description about adjacent numbers and spacing, as that cannot lead to ambiguity. Then you can use a different winning criterion (such as code golf), and people can be flexible in the output format they choose depending on what allows for the shortest code in their language.

Comment: Looks like I was commenting on the version before your edit - apologies if some of this no longer applies...

Comment: @trichoplax thanks. I believe your words have convinced me that subjective 'readable' judgement is not that good for this challenge.

Comment: @trichoplax I have modified the problem a little bit to take out that requirement

Comment: One way to test that your requirements are objective is to write a validator program that takes the output of a submission as input and indicates whether it is valid. If you can write this program then the requirements are objective, and it will also ensure everyone is working with the same definition. Any problems you run into while writing it will also help to identify any ambiguities in the requirements.

Comment: Can I post this abandoned proposal?

Comment: @programmer5000 Sure. Mention me if it doesn't bother you. XD

Answer (score 2):

### Permutation-Tolerant Hello World

*Inspired by [Fault-Tolerant Hello World (a.k.a. the Interview)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/fault-tolerant-hello-world-a-k-a-the-interview).*

#### Task

Write a program that prints `Hello World`. Sounds easy, right? Ok, lets challenge up a bit : your (real) task is to maximum the number of permutations of the characters of your code that produce a code that when executed prints `Hello World` as well.

Hmm, I even got myself confused with that last sentence, so let's see an example :

Consider the following code (it's good enough to understand the principle, but as I'll explain later, the score of such a code will be pretty low) :
(it's Perl code, and if you don't trust me when I say it works, you can run it with `perl -e 'code'` in your terminal)

```
print+("Hello World")
```

When ran, it prints `Hello World`.
Well, the following permutations of the code also print `Hello World` :

```
+(print"Hello World")
+print("Hello World")
(print+"Hello World")
()+print"Hello World"
```

Note that only permutations that produce a code that differs from the previous ones should be considered. For instance, the original code where the two `l` have been swapped isn't a valid permutation.

#### Scoring

The score of your solution is the number of bytes of your code divided by the number of valid permutations. Lowest score wins. In case of draw, the earliest solution wins.
For instance, my example above was 21 bytes long, and had 5 valid permutations (note that it includes the original code), so its score is `21/5 = 4.2`.

---

#### For the sandbox

(1- Does it sound like a nice challenge?
 2- Is it clear? )

3- I don't really what tags to add...

4- I'm not sure about the scoring method. In particular, I wonder if just adding useless stuff around the "print hello world" part of the program (no matter the language) might allow a lot of permutations to be valid with some languages.
I'd like the code where all permutations are valid and that is the longest possible to win. And I'm not sure my scoring method will produce such results.

5- Is a "print hello world" program the more relevant? Actually I think that the code could do anything : calculating oeis sequence, drawing rectangles or whatever, as long as all the permutations produces the same behavior. But then some people might play on internal behavior of languages such as "by default, this language prints `1`", so every permutation of any source will print `1`, or stuffs like this... Any thoughts?

6- I thought about making this challenge harder by actually changing "as much permutations as possible should be valid" to "all permutations should be valid". This will of course prevent a lot of languages to compete, but might result in creative and nice answers.

Comment: If I've read this challenge correctly, [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) is going to win with (astronomical number) divided by (astronomical number factorial). Of course, this could still be a good challenge in other languages regardless, but the scoring as is means that it's beneficial to pad the program as long as possible since the denominator grows factorially compared to the linear numerator - so yeah I think a different scoring method might be necessary (no good ideas off the top of my head though)

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks for your comment. I think that this sentence `Note that only permutations that produce a code that differs from the previous ones should be considered` (which I wrote right after the examples) will prevent Unary to win since it will have 0 valid permutations.

Comment: Oh right, jumped the gun and missed that sentence. In that case I think you can use [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) instead? (since it's basically Unary but you can choose the chars)

Comment: Something like `print"Hello World";123456789123456789` still produces a huge number of permutations.

Comment: @xnor indeed. I was worried (cf question 4 for the sandbox) that something like that could be possible, and it obviously is. So ask for all the possible permutations to be valid would be a better challenge? Or should I just drop that challenge?

Comment: If using a language with nops, [hello world program][arbitrary number of nops] will be even worse than xnors example

Answer (score 2):

## Display an xkcd

xkcd is everyone's favorite webcomic, and you will be writing a program that will bring a little bit more humor to us all.
Your objective in this challenge is to write a program which will take a number as input and display that xkcd and its alt-text (mousover text).

### Input

Your program will take an integer as input and display that xkcd: for example, an input of 1500 should display the comic "Upside-Down Map" at xkcd.com/1500, and then either print its alt-text to the console or display it with the image.

[image: Due to their proximity across the channel, there's long been tension between North Korea and the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Southern Ireland.]
`Due to their proximity across the channel, there's long been tension between North Korea and the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Southern Ireland.`

Your program should also be able to function without any input, and perform the same task for the most recent xkcd found at xkcd.com, and it should always display the most recent one even when a new one goes up.

You do not have to get the image directly from xkcd.com, you can use another database as long as it is up-to-date and already existed before this challenge went up.

You may *not* display the entire webpage in an iframe or similar.

You can handle the case that there isn't an image for a particular comic (i.e. it is interactive or the program was passed a number greater than the amount of comics that have been released) in any reasonable way you wish, including throwing an exception, or printing out an at least single-character string, as long as it somehow signifies to the user that there isn't an image for that input.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the fewest bytes wins!

Comment: I think this is probably a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91847/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's similar, however I think that it's different enough to warrant it's own question. That puzzle required the creation of a bot that will display any new xkcd that comes up, this one just displays one, but it can be any requested one. In addition, my puzzle also requires the title text to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

## Cryptographically secure favicon.

Create a cryptographically secure program which will take a string of up to 24 characters and create an image such that differing inputs can be "easily" distinguished visually. The goal being that the end image is visually appealling, and it is impossible to reverse engineer the string.

**The challenge**

- Create a program or function which takes an input string and output an image in any desired format.
- Pick a secret password and post an image generated with that password along with your submission code.
- Optionally post some sample inputs and outputs.

OR

- Try to post someone else's password (or just any existing collision with that password).

**The scoring**

- Out of the posts whose password has not been cracked the post with the most upvotes after an arbitrary time period set sometime in the significant future.

Voters are encouraged to vote based on ingenuity and aesthetic appeal, but can vote for whatever posts they like.

Comment: This is essentially the same as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25443/194 and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95836/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think this challenge is fundamentally different in that the format of the output is not fixed, and the method of encoding the image should be interested.

Comment: To be clear, unlike those two questions, the answers of this question should usually output visually distinguishable images for different secrets, instead of

Comment: I'd call this too broad. On top of hashing, find a pleasing way to represent it is largely a question of art and aesthetics. Having different outputs be visually distinguishable happens is easy if the hash function already brings close inputs to far outputs.

Comment: I have to agree with xnor here, as stated, this is too broad. However, I think the idea is interesting, although  there will always be the issue of defining what cryptography is "too good" (and thereby already disallowed). Also, it might be that the good essence of this challenge is completely covered by the links from Peter

Comment: @xnor we have had "art"challenges throughot the graphical output tag.

Answer (score 2):

### Killer Sudoku Pro suggestions

Regular Sudoku is just about creating a enhanced Latin square and features no arithmetic on the digits 1-9 which are traditionally used.

Killer Sudoku goes further: the puzzle is tiled with polyominoes which are labelled with the sum of the cells which they cover. Additionally, no polyomino may cover two cells with the same digit, even though those digits would otherwise have been legal because they are not in the same row, column or square. It is therefore helpful to be aware of the inverse relationship: given a quantity of cells and a sum, calculate the possible values of the cells. This is also useful for solving Kakuro, which also features sums of distinct digits.

Killer Sudoku Pro goes one further step: rather than being the sum of the cells, any of the four basic operations may be used. The digits in the cells must then satisfy that basic operation.

Given a target, operator and number of cells, I would like you write a program or function to output sets of distinct digits that satisfy the arithmetic expression. To minimise the necessary output I only want distinct combinations of digits, rather than all the potential permutations. (Some puzzle creators will not allow all the permutations for subtraction and division, so taking that into account would unnecessarily complicate the question.)

Examples (example input format: target, operator, (number of cells); output format: answers " or "-separated, digits operator-separated in descending order):

```
14+(4) -> 8+3+2+1 or 7+4+2+1 or 6+5+2+1 or 6+4+3+1 or 5+4+3+2
4-(3) -> 9-4-1 or 9-3-2 or 8-3-1 or 7-2-1
24×(3) -> 8×3×1 or 6×4×1 or 4×3×2
2÷(2) -> 8÷4 or 6÷3 or 4÷2 or 2÷1
```

I/O may be in any reasonable format as long as it is clear what is going on, so you can't encode the operations as specific integers, although using `*` and `/` or their Unicode code points instead is OK, and answers must use a different separator to the digits in each answer.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: Could be worth noting that the only numbers to be considered are 1-9 (or you could add a third input for 1-N)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I didn't realise `10` was a digit, but I guess I should specifically exclude `0`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice "digit" :)

Comment: I find the sentence begining "*Some puzzle creators allow the digits from the polyomino to be used in any order*" to be odd to the point of disruptive. It presupposes a "correct" order to the elements of the polyomino which isn't obvious, and the logical connection is weak. I suggest rewriting it along the lines of "*You should only output one representative suggestion for each distinct set of digits; so e.g. one but not both of `9-4-1` and `9-1-4`*", possibly with a footnote to discuss variations between puzzle setters in whether order is significant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The justification is only `9-4-1` and `9-1-4` actually evaluate to 4, so some creators will only use `4-` for those two permutations, but I decided the question needed editing anyway.

Comment: My point about permutations was that if the polyomino is e.g. the X pentomino then the "natural" order of the cells is up for debate. But I think the new wording side-steps that concern.

Answer (score 2):

## Interpret Developers

Developers is a joke language that parodies an incident at a Microsoft Developer's conference where Steve Ballmer is supposed to have chanted the word developers at least 14 times in a row. It is basically Brainfuck with a few extensions. It appeared briefly in the Wikipedia in the beginning of 2006, but it has not reappeared anywhere since its deletion. [[source](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Developers)]

Your job today is to ressurect this beautiful language, and create an interpreter in the fewest number of bytes. You will have to implement the following commands, which contain their Brainfuck and C equivalents:

```
| Key            | BF Equiv | C Equiv         |
|----------------|----------|-----------------|
| "Developers"   | +        | ++*ptr;         |
| "Developers"*2 | -        | --*ptr;         |
| "Developers"*3 | >        | ++ptr;          |
| "Developers"*4 | <        | --ptr;          |
| "Developers"*5 | ,        | *ptr=getchar(): |
| "Developers"*6 | .        | putchar(*ptr);  |
| "Developers"*7 | [        | while (*ptr) {  |
| "Developers"*8 | ]        | }               |
```

As this is standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the aim of the game is to create the shortest interpreter possible.

## Specification

Your interpreter should behave accordingly:

- Developers/Developerz commands are separated by any whitespace.
- Anything that is not a valid command should be ignored.
- There will never be any more than 8 `Developers` (or 3 `Developerz`) present in the program that are not separated by whitespace.
- Input can be interactive or provided at runtime.

## Bonus

If you would like to earn bonus points, you can also implement the following three extensions to the Developers language. These do not have a Brainfuck equivalent.

```
| Key            | C Equiv                          |
|----------------|----------------------------------|
| "Developerz"   | Sleep(strlen(buffer)*10);        |
| "Developerz"*2 | system("cls");||system("clear"); |
| "Developerz"*3 | *p = rand() & 0xFF;              |
```

If the goal of these is not clear:

- `Developerz` should sleep the program for 10ms for ever character in an input string
- `DeveloperzDeveloperz` should clear the screen.
- `DevelopersDeveloperzDeveloperz` should assign the currently pointed to cell to a random integer between 0 and 255.

For each command you implement, you may multiply your score by `0.75`. Thus, by implementing all three, your score would be `42.1875%` of the byte count.

Comment: That's a pretty big bonus for implementing the three extensions. That's probably either such a hard task no one will go for it or such a huge bonus everyone will <i>have</i> to go for it.

Comment: @Pavel I had made it that much because I felt that these bonuses would only benefit languages that were verbose enough that they probably wouldn't beat a Jelly/Python/05AB1E answer (except for the random number functionality), and I dont think the shorter languages tend to have sleep functions or system calls available to them.

Comment: This seems like a dupe of "Interpret BF" to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex Crossword

### Challenge

Write the shortest program that outputs a valid solution to a regex crossword. A [regex crossword](https://regexcrossword.com/) is a crossword that has regular expressions for the clues, like in this Puzzling SE puzzle: [The Prognosticator](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45430/the-prognosticator).

#### Terminology your program needs to know (simplified from [here](https://regexcrossword.com/))

```
Quantifiers:
x*     0 or more of x (any group instruction)
x+     1 or more of x
x?     0 or 1 of x
x{y}   Exactly y of x
x{y,}  y or more of x
x{,y}  y or less of x

Groups:
.      Any char except \n
(x|y)     Strings x or y (may be multichar), indexed from 1 from the start of clue
(xyz)     Multichar string literal, indexed from 1 from the start of clue
[xyz]     Any of characters x, y or z
[^xyz]    Not the characters x, y or z
[^x|y]    Not x or y (may be multichar)
[B-N]     Letters between B and N inclusive (any letters, caps or not)
[3-6]     Numbers between 3 and 6 inclusive (any digits)
[B-NR-Z]  Multiple ranges (could be digit ranges as well)

Escape sequences:
\7  Get the result of the bracketed instruction indexed 7 (any num)
\r  Literal r where r is a character used in an instruction above
\\  Literal backslash
\W  a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore)
\w  Not a character in \W
\d  A digit
\D  Not a digit
\s  Space
\S  Not a space
```

### Test Cases

Input can be any format, examples use:
    Width Length
    Top down clues from left to right
    Bottom down clues from left to right (if they don't exist, newline)
    Left across clues from top to bottom
    Right across clues from top to bottom (if they don't exist, newline)

Output must be the completed grid.

Sample input (from [here](https://regexcrossword.com/)):

```
Input 1:
2 2
[^SPEAK]+
(EP|IP|EF)


(HE|LL|O)+
[PLEASE]+


Output 1:
HE
LP
Input 2:
2 2
[COBRA]+
(AB|O|OR)+


(.)+\1
[^ABRC]+


Output 2:
OO
OO
Input 3:
2 2
.?.+
.+


[*]+
/+


Output 3:
**
//
Input 4:
3 4
(.)\1(.)\2
[C\sOU]+
[^PU\sH]+
[PIF]+
.*[OWE]*
(TN|LF|TF)+
.[LUH]+
(P|K)[^U]+
.*C+[TIF]
(NO|ONE|ION)*
.*(L)+
[PUF\s]*
[TIC]*
[NOI\sE]+
Output 4:
PUL
P F
ICT
ION
Input 5:
3 7
[^ro\se]*(whe|who)
[are](.)[saint]+\1(v)
.{2}[st\sel]+
[^vys]+
.(\ssai).*
(le|\st|s|or)+
(rr|fro)*
[^saint]+
[\sush]*
[a\si]+
[with]*
[hel\s]+
.*
[fr\so]+
(m\s|sm)[rose]
(s|us)+
[^aw](a).*
[^hear]+
.*[fil]
(ve|o|vo)+
Output 5:
fro
m r
uss
ia 
wit
h l
ove
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Standard loopholes apply, and no built-ins for `regex` testing or matching. Your program must terminate in a reasonable amount of time.

You may assume that each input has exactly one solution.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) [crossword](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossword) [puzzle-solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-solver)

Comment: 1. "*No built-ins*" means "*You may not answer this question*". Every program uses built-ins except zero-byte ones in the languages which support them. "*No built-ins for regex testing or matching*" would, on the other hand, not be unreasonable. 2. There's currently no constraint requiring the answers to complete the test cases before the heat death of the universe. Is this intentional?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for that, I've added your suggestions in. I'm new to code golf.

Answer (score 2):

[Please do my Martian homework posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101727/please-do-my-martian-homework)

## For Sandbox, please note

This was originally conceived of as two related challenges; **Please do my Martian homework** and **Please grade my Martian homework**.

Though the task itself is different, the basic description of the task (that is, what is a Martian essay) is the same (though I may edit it later anyway), but just to avoid confusion:

- **Please *do* my Martian homework** was posted
- **Please *grade* my Martian homework** is what's left

## Please Grade my Martian Homework

### History

Around the turn of the 20th century, spiritualist Catherine-Elise Müller allegedly communicated with Martians.  During somnambulatory trances, she would write out Martian scripts.  Psychologist Théodore Flourney discovered her Martian writings were very similar to her native French, and in his book "From India to the Planet Mars", he documented Catherine's Martian alphabet.  The following is loosely based on that alphabet with an extended mythos.

### Problem Description

The Martian language has 21 characters, shown here next to each Latin equivalent:

[image]

Unfortunately, there's no Unicode for Martian (despite Mars being part of the universe), so we're stuck using Latin characters.

Whereas in English our phonemes break out into two major types (consonants/vowels) which we loosely map to letters, Martian has three letter types:

- The vowels: a e i m n o u
- The hard consonants: b c d g k p t
- The soft consonants: f h l r s v z

In addition to this, the Martian language contains a single punctuation mark--the period.

A **Martian word** is a set of 3 to 9 letters.  All Martian words have at least one vowel, one hard consonant, and one soft consonant (in any arrangement).  For example, `fng`, `cdaz`, `vpi`, and `pascal` are Martian words.

A **Martian sentence** is a set of 3 to 9 Martian words delimited by spaces and followed by a period.

A **Martian paragraph** is a set of 3 to 9 Martian sentences, delimited by spaces, and followed by a newline.

A **Martian essay** is a collection of Martian paragraphs that contains no contiguous word repetitions.

A **contiguous word repetition** is any construct S S where S is a contiguous set of words.  Note that this definition ignores sentence and paragraph boundaries.

### Challenge

The Martian homework assignment is to write an essay between 729 and 810 words.  The essay is graded on a pass/fail basis; pass simply means it's a valid Martian essay according to the above definitions, and fail means not pass.

Your challenge is to write a function or program that accepts data as input, and returns a truthy value if that data is a valid Martian essay between 729 and 810 words, or a falsey value if it is not.  (Don't forget that you must fail the input if there is a contiguous repetition).

This is code golf.  Shortest code in bytes wins.  Standard loopholes disallowed.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

### TBD

Post link to examples in first challenge?  Repeat examples? Should second challenge still have word counting?

Comment: Whoops; most of the post is almost identical so I thought it was the same, but the task is indeed different. I've deleted my original comment.

Answer (score 2):

## Balancing Act

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

**Edit: Challenge Live [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99545/add-weight-to-one-side-of-a-see-saw-to-balance-it)**

A see-saw (supposedly from the French 'ci-ça', meaning 'this-that') forms a third of the holy trinity of playground equipment, along with the similarly ubiquitous slide and swing. A see-saw is in perfect balance if, and only if, the sum of the moments on each side are equivalent. A see-saw can therefore be balanced by adding a specific quantity of weight to the side with the lower moment sum; achieving this is your goal for this challenge.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to take a depiction of a see-saw as input and output it again, with weight added to one end of the see-saw to balance it.

**Input**

Your program must take, in any reasonable format, an ASCII see-saw such as the following:

```
100             100
-------------------
         ^
```

The first line contains two numbers, each representing weights on the see-saw. Exactly one weight is present on each side, each acting on the very end of its side of the plank. Weights are guaranteed to be integers, and always align with their corresponding end of the plank. These numbers will never overlap the fulcrum (`^`).

The second line represents the 'plank' of the see-saw. Each dash (`-`) represents an equal length to each other dash, with the sole exception of the dash directly over the fulcrum (`^`), which has no length.

The third line represents the fulcrum of the see-saw. This fulcrum is marked by the only character that is not a space on this line, a circumflex ('^'). The fulcrum can be positioned anywhere along the length of the plank in a valid input so long as enough space is left so that the numbers representing weights do not overlap the fulcrum in either the input or the output.

The input is guaranteed to have three lines, and have no white-space prior to or after the characters that constitute the see-saw (excepting, of course, the third line, which requires it).

**Output**

For output, the same see-saw depiction should be printed to stdout, but with one (and only one) of the weights replaced with a larger weight, so as to balance the see-saw. Inputs are guaranteed to make this possible using integers alone. Therefore, weights must be shown without decimal points or any other similar notations. If your language does not use stdout you should go by community / meta consensus on output. Trailing newlines are fine but any other changes to the depiction format are probably not OK.

## Exemplification

**Test Inputs and Corresponding Outputs**

Input 1

```
12                22
--------------------
             ^
```

Output 1

```
12                26
--------------------
             ^
```

---

Input 2

```
42       42
-----------
     ^
```

Output 2

```
42       42
-----------
     ^
```

---

Input 3

```
3             16
----------------
        ^
```

Output 3

```
14            16
----------------
        ^
```

---

Input 4

```
1                56
-------------------
    ^
```

Output 4

```
196              56
-------------------
    ^
```

**Reference Implementation - Python 3**

```
# Takes a list of strings as input
def balance_seesaw(lines):
    weights = [int(w.strip()) for w in lines[0].split()]

    length  = len(lines[1])
    pivot   = lines[2].find("^")
    left_length    = pivot
    right_length   = length - 1 - pivot

    left_torque  = weights[0] * left_length
    right_torque = weights[1] * right_length

    if left_torque > right_torque:
        weights[1] = left_torque // right_length
    elif right_torque > left_torque:
        weights[0] = right_torque // left_length

    weights = [str(w) for w in weights]

    string_gap = " " * (length - sum(len(w) for w in weights))
    lines[0] = weights[0] + string_gap + weights[1]

    print("\n".join(lines))

balance_seesaw(["1                56",
                "-------------------",
                "    ^              "])
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins counted in bytes. Check meta if counting bytes is awkward in your language.
- Standard rules/loopholes apply.
- Input must be taken in a reasonable format. A non-exhaustive list of appropriate formats are given as follows:

  - A single string with lines separated by newline characters
  - A list of strings, each string represented a line
  - A 2D Array or Matrix of characters

### Sandbox Notes

Please comment on any parts of the spec, especially input / output requirements, that you find confusing or ambiguous. I haven't written a challenge before so I'm open to the fact that there's quite a bit I've missed. Any and all feedback welcome.

Some users in the comments have rightly pointed out similarities between this challenge and others; please weigh in as to if you think this is a dupe or a unique challenge in its own right. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A pretty decent first challenge. It's pretty similar to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54311/balance-a-set-of-weights-on-a-seesaw), but yours is, in my opinion, different enough to not be a duplicate. It's also pretty close to [this one](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10521/42963) posted in the Sandbox a few posts down. I *think* that all three are different enough to not be dupes, but I'll hold off on final judgment to hear what others say.

Comment: @TimmyD thanks for the welcome! Looks like I need to up my searching game! I understand if this is deemed a duplicate but it seems to differ in a fair few ways from the others at least.

Comment: Welcome! For me, a nice challenge and well explained with clear examples. I'll also hold back on the dupe side but agree with TimmyD that it may be different enough. Well done for using the Sandbox anyway. It' a shame that more contributors don't. I'm going to +1 just for that.

Comment: @ElPedro thanks, appreciate the feedback and the vote.

Comment: Having read (again) through the examples mentioned by @TimmyD I would not say this is a dupe. Possibly mention that it is related though.

Answer (score 2):

## Generate me a QFP chip!

## [This challenge is now live!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102456/60951)

QFP is a type of form factor for an electrical component where pins come out the sides of a chip.  Here are is a picture of a typical QFP component: [image]

<sup>you can see that the general formula is to have 4 sides of equal numbers of pins.</sup>

Your challenge is to create a program that takes in an integer, thich represents the number of pins on one side, and creates an ASCII QFP component with numbered pins.

### Input:

a single integer which represents the number of pins on one side

### Output:

An ascii QFP chip with an apropriate pinout.

### Example:

input:1

```
  4
 ┌┴┐
1┤ ├3
 └┬┘
  2
```

input:2

```
  87
 ┌┴┴┐
1┤  ├6
2┤  ├5
 └┬┬┘
  34
```

input:12

```
   444444444333
   876543210987
  ┌┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┐
 1┤            ├36
 2┤            ├35
 3┤            ├34
 4┤            ├33
 5┤            ├32
 6┤            ├31
 7┤            ├30
 8┤            ├29
 9┤            ├28
10┤            ├27
11┤            ├26
12┤            ├25
  └┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┘
   111111122222
   345678901234
```

### Rules:

- all QFP chips must be enclosed and sealed as well as ascii provides. spacing is of utmost importance.
- pin numbering must be done as in the examples (Read left to right, top to bottom, numbered counter clockwise)
- You may start numbering at 0, but this must not affect the chip (an input of 12 still needs 12 pins per side)
- The only valid characers in your output are `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,┌,┴,┐,├,┘,┬,└,┤`, spaces, and newlines.

This is a codegolf, and as such, The code with the least number of bytes wins! Good Luck!

Comment: @Geobits thank you! fixed.

Comment: Do we have to use boxdrawing characters or can we use `+` instead? If you use them, it means languages that don't support nonascii can't compete. Also what encodings are allowed? codepage 437? UTF-8? Include the codepoints in the question.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt thank you for your feedback! It was my intention to keep those languages out of the challenge.

Comment: Now that this has been posted you should consider editing it down to a link and deleting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Find the optimal sorting network

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

[Sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) are an abstract model of "wires" carrying numbers, which outputs them sorted.

A comparator in a sorting network works as follows:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sorting-network-comparator-demonstration.svg]

This is the optimal sorting network for 4 numbers:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SimpleSortingNetworkFullOperation.svg]

Since there are two kinds of "optimal" sorting networks people care about, we are going for the least number of comparators (those vertical lines).

---

Given a non-negative integer `n` (so yes, 0 and 1 need to be supported), output a list of comparators which designates an optimal sorting network for `n` inputs. The "comparators" are a pair of indices which say which indices in the working array to compare / swap. The indices must be 0-based.

So for the example sorting network, this would be a valid output (viewing 0 as the top wire):

```
(0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)
```

As would this:

```
(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (0, 1), (1, 2)
```

Additionally, any whitespace is ignored (except for tokenizing), and any non-digit is considered whitespace, so this is also a valid output:

```
0 2 1 3 2 3 0 1 1 2
```

And also:

```
(0, 2)
(1
 3)
((2, 3, 0), 1)
(1, 2)
```

Furthermore, functions may simply return some iterable that - when flattened - gives the list of numbers in the correct order.

Comment: I have an algorithm to do this; it's `O((n^2)! n! n)`, so very very slow. It might compute size 3, but not size 4.

Comment: I think it's worth giving an example of a sorting network in action on some input.

Comment: What are the bounds on `n`? Obviously it doesn't make sense to have `n < 0`, but do answers need to handle `n=0` and `n=1`?

Comment: @Justin are you still planning to release this challenge? I'm asking because I wanted to make a very similar challenge that would probably be considered a dupe.

Comment: @flawr No, go for it

Answer (score 2):

## ROT-13? More like ROT-Rand!

This challenge is to take the following list of characters (ASCII 32 to 126):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Randomly shuffle it:

```
wypP+]`=3&IJ6*xAh{zi_l4Y#k~S F?-oReU;(0m,Z5'trs!aLCQ/g}OjM<u[qE2)BTVb$>19%c:HW@8."nD\Nf7dXKv^|G
```

Take in an input string:

```
ROT-Rand!
```

Then replace the characters in the string, with their new shuffled equivalents:

```
C!/*CB@by
```

Using this methodology on large ASCII-based/dictionary based texts would result in something that is decipherable using much trial and error and would be a decent way to encode a long message.

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
wypP+]`=3&IJ6*xAh{zi_l4Y#k~S F?-oReU;(0m,Z5'trs!aLCQ/g}OjM<u[qE2)BTVb$>19%c:HW@8."nD\Nf7dXKv^|G
 ^           ^                                    ^              ^  ^         ^^    ^
 !           -                                    R              a  d         no    t
```

## Rules

1. Your only input is the text to be "encrypted".
2. Your output is the encrypted string.
3. The ASCII list must be randomly shuffled, built-ins are allowed.
4. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest in bytes wins.

Comment: 1. I'm guessing from context that "*their new shuffled equivalents*" means that we're generating a random substitution cipher, but I don't see any actual definition of the equivalence. 2. If I'm correct, this is pretty boring, but could be made more interesting with the (justifiable) modification that the substitution should be a random *derangement* rather than just a random permutation. That will probably force most languages to do more than just apply two built-ins.

Comment: @PeterTaylor derangement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 2):

## Roflcopter [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Your task is to print animated helicopter.

## Rules

1. Animation should contain at least two frames.
2. Delay between frames is up to you, but rotation of airscrews should be visible.
3. Helicopter could be very simple (simpler than standard roflcopter showed below) but it should leave no doubt what is it. All ASCII chars are allowed.
4. No caption below needed.
5. Printing animation to file would be hard, although all standard output destinations are allowed.
6. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so etc.

[image: roflcopter]

I believe I can fly.

Comment: You should probably place the ASCII of each frame of the Roflcopter in the challenge. Also, is the `ROFL COPTER!!!` at the end necessary?

Comment: +1 For caption necessity or not, I updated question. In my opinion providing frames will make challenge too easy.

Comment: So will the design of the Roflcopter be the same for all submissions, with the same plane body, rotors and stuff?

Comment: It's up to users, how exactly it will look, but it should be helicopter-like. Ok, I think you're right, this task is too ambiguous. I will try with another question.

Comment: You can just standardise the copter itself, and it shouldn't be ambiguous...

Answer (score 2):

## Hexasweep: A two-part challenge

### Part 1: The solver [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task is to solve a Hexasweep puzzle.

A Hexasweep puzzle is set out on a grid of diamonds arranged in hexagonal shapes, of which the board looks like a hexagon, like so:

```
         _____
        /\    \
  _____/ X\____\_____
 /\    \  / XX /\    \
/X \____\/____/X \____\
\ X/ XX /\    \ X/    /
 \/____/  \____\/____/
 /\    \  / X  /\    \
/  \____\/____/  \____\
\  / XX /\    \  / XX /
 \/____/  \____\/____/
       \ X/    /
        \/____/
```

The above image is composed of 7 hexagons (21 diamonds), and is thus a Hexasweep puzzle of size 2. If you want to expand it, cover the current Hexasweep puzzle with more hexagons (so that there are 19 hexagons - that will make a Hexasweep puzzle of size 3).

Each diamond can contain 0, 1 or 2 "bombs", with bombs depicted as `X` above.

The above image would be read from top to bottom, starting from the left:

```
2,0,0,2,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2
```

That is now the "condensed form" of the puzzle.

Numbers are marked on "intersection points", to show how many bombs are on the diamonds which are touching those intersection points - the intersection points of this grid are shown below using `O`.

```
         _____
        /\    \
  _____/  OO___\_____
 /\    \  OO   /\    \
/  OO___OO___OO  OO___\
\  OO   OO   OO  OO   /
 \/___OO  OO___OO____/
 /\   OO  OO   OO    \
/  OO___OO___OO  OO___\
\  OO   OO   OO  OO   /
 \/____/  OO___\/____/
       \  OO   /
        \/____/
```

As you can see, there are two "types" of intersection points - those with 3 diamonds touching it, and those with 6 (the one that are touching the edge of the board aren't counted):

```
  _____
 /\  XX\
/X OO___\
\ XOO   /
 \/____/

       /\
 _____/X \_____
 \ XX \ X/    /
  \____OO____/
  / XX OO  X \
 /____/  \____\
      \ X/
       \/
```

The two intersections would be marked with `4` and `8` respectively.

In the original Hexasweep puzzle above, the intersection numbers would be:

```
   3
4 5 4 2
 2 1 3
2 4 1 2
   1
```

Which would be condensed to:

```
3,4,5,4,2,2,1,3,2,4,1,2,1
```

Given an input in this "condensed form", you must output the original puzzle, in "condensed form" (see above).

#### Specs:

- Any delimiter for the "condensed form" as input are allowed (it doesn't have to be `,` separating the numbers).
- You may output a list, or a string with any delimiter.
- Your program must be generalised: it must be able to solve Hexasweep puzzles of any size (at least up to size 4).
- If there is more than 1 possible answer, your program must output the single character `N`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

If there is a tie, the earlier post is declared the winner.

### Part 2: The maker [meta-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-golf)

Your task is to generate the smallest Hexasweep puzzle with a single solution that encodes a binary number.

Because any diamond in a Hexasweep puzzle can have either 1 or 2 bombs (if the diamond has bombs), you can encode binary numbers into it. In this puzzle (condensed form):

```
2,0,0,2,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2
```

The only digits that matter are the non-zero digits, so this turns into:

```
2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2
```

Decrement each number by 1:

```
111001011
```

Which is equal to `459`.

Your task is to make a program that generates that Hexasweep puzzle in the smallest grid with a single solution.

#### Specs:

- You must output the condensed form of the Hexasweep puzzle.
- You can output either an array of numbers, or a string with any delimiter.
- You will be tested on all positive integers from `10,000` to `15,000`, and your program is expected to return a value for any integer in `10` minutes.

Your final score is the total size grid for every test integer added together (so if you get a size `3` grid for every number, your final score would be `15,000`). The lowest score is declared the winner.

If there is a tie, the earlier post is declared the winner.

---

### Meta:

- Should this be one challenge or two? If it's one challenge, should the score just be added up for both programs?
- Any improvements in explanation?
- Is this a dupe?

Comment: Can I post this abandoned proposal?

Answer (score 2):

## ASCII-betical order

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [printable-ascii](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printable-ascii)

---

The full printable ASCII set (chars 32-126) in ascending order looks like this:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Your task is to create a program or function which takes in an integer **n** and outputs the **n**<sup>th</sup> item of an [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) sequence. The catch: your score is the length of your code, plus thrice the number of ASCII chars in your code *not* included in the longest strictly increasing substring.

### Rules

A valid strictly increasing substring of your code is defined as so:

- Each character within the substring, except the first, must have a higher ASCII value than the previous.

Other rules:

- The sequence may be 0- or 1-indexed.
- The sequence you choose may not be a constant sequence, such as [A000012](http://oeis.org/A000012).
- Entries may only include printable ASCII and newlines. Newlines are ignored when calculating the longest increasing substring.

### Examples

This JavaScript function outputs [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027) (the natural numbers):

```
n=>[]^n
```

The longest increasing substring of characters is `=>[]^n`. Therefore, the score is 7 + 3 × (7 - 6) = **10**.

This function does exactly the same thing:

```
_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=>[]^_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The longest increasing substring is `=>[]^_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. The score is 59 + 3 × (59 - 32) = **140**.

This function also does the same thing:

```
n/*!"#$%&'()*/=>[]^n
```

The longest increasing substring is `!"#$%&'()*/=>[]^n`. Therefore, the score is 20 + 3 × (20 - 17) = **29**.

**The lowest score wins.**

---

### Sandbox questions

- Is the scoring system sufficient?
- Is there a better option for the challenge?

  - Output n'th item in some OEIS sequence
  - Output first n items of some OEIS sequence
  - Output the score of the input
  - etc.
- What about languages with extended code pages? Should only the ASCII chars be counted, or should the bytes of the program be considered instead?
- Any other concerns?

Comment: I like this version much better. Some ideas: maybe force to choose a non costant oeis sequence? I'm not sure about scoring, seems that standard golfing without caring about increasing ascii can still get a pretty good score... Rule to use only ascii chars in code seems to just be a limit to golfing languages. For the title, i liked the term _ASCIIbetical order_ used in a comment to the previous proposal .)

Comment: @Leo I like the non-constant-sequence idea. I've modified the scoring system to make it a little easier to use (see examples), but I still don't like it because if you need to use that variable name 3 times, it's not worth it, and if you only need it once, it's doubly worth it. Perhaps something taking into account the number and length of individual runs would work better, but I have no idea how to work that out...

Comment: Would something like `f n = if ( length "#$% ... |}~" == 92) then n else 0` be valid? For golfing languages the length check won't be much overhead.

Comment: I'd prefer the scoring to work like this (which would be simpler): length, plus three times the number of characters *in your code* which are not part of the longest substring. That'd prevent people putting the whole ASCIIbet in a string and using a checksum (or length check) to make sure it hadn't been changed. In other words, it'd would encourage programs which were mostly formed of increasing ASCII, rather than programs which contained a lot of increasing ASCII (i.e. favour proportion over length).

Comment: @nimi Sorry, I missed your comment. I suppose that would be valid. The scoring system would have to account for that.

Comment: @ais523 I like that idea; however, as it's currently written, that would give the first two examples scores of 16 and 140, respectively. I'd like to give the second example a much lower score, if possible, but I'm not sure how to do this, and it may not be a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. The second example isn't actually any different from the first in terms of AST, it just has a bunch of junk characters written somewhere (in this case, a variable name) that the program doesn't parse them (with an equal number of characters outside to balance).

Comment: @ais523 OK, I've changed the scoring algorithm. I've also removed the "you can't be able to remove any chars in the substring" rule for now, as it now seems superfluous.

Comment: The problem with this scoring is that the winner would probably be a 2 byte program in a golfing language scoring 2 points (or a 1 byte program scoring 1 point, I bet someone will find it).

Comment: @Leo: I guess even 0 bytes is possible by using a language that takes implicitly input, puts in on the stack (does nothing for 0 bytes) and outputs the stack when the program stops. This is sequence A000027, the natural numbers .

Comment: @Leo Yes, that's a very good point. It's so hard to come up with a good formula.... Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: @ETHproductions Maybe (length of longest increasing sequence)^2/(length of whole program) ? Highest score wins, max would be 95 for a program composed by exactly the whole sequence

Comment: @Leo The problem with that would be it goes back to rewarding solutions containing the whole string with a length check... (For example, ``n=> !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"[90]?m:n`` in JavaScript scores 84.346)

Comment: Printing the first *n* elements of the OEIS sequence (as oppposed to the *n*th element) would probably rule out zero-byte solutions (although not 1-byte solutions, especially due to the existence of range operators). Perhaps you need to decide on a specific task for the program to do, rather than leaving it open.

Comment: I don't understand why you would prohibit constant sequences but not prohibit the identity function, which in most languages will be shorter than some constant sequences. I also think that allowing everyone to pick their own sequence to implement pushes this under "Too broad".

Comment: I read "your score is the length of your code, plus thrice the number of ASCII chars in your code not included in the longest strictly increasing substring" three times, then looked at the examples, then looked at it again, and *then* I understood it. I would suggest replacing it with something like "your score is `L + 3*X`, where `L` is the length of your code, and `X` is the number of bytes that aren't part of its longest strictly increasing substring"

Comment: or even "`3*L - 2*I`, where `L` is the length of your code and `I` is the length of its longest strictly increasing substring," which is numerically the same but easier to understand. (At least I think it's the same. It depends whether you're talking about *distinct* characters or not. I'm assuming not. You should clarify that.)

Comment: A separate comment: you should replace "ASCII chars" with "bytes". That would allow more languages to compete.

Comment: As a follow-on to my previous comment about the identity function being shorter in some languages, as things stand I could submit a zero-byte answer in GolfScript. When a zero-byte answer is possible, the question has a serious problem.

Comment: This could be interesting for non esolangs but a lot of languages will be able to submit the empty program. Also, I think you should change characters to bytes, as Nathaniel suggested.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't have time yet to overhaul the challenge with these suggestions (I agree with most of them), but I will when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

### The social network [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

On my social network, two users are "friends" if their name share a common letter.
For exemple, `bob` and `bill` are friends, as they share the letter `b`.

Given a list of user names:

- display a **falsy** value if there exist in the list two distinct users `x` and `y` that cannot be related through a friendship chain;
- else, display a **truthy** value.

**Examples**

`abc cde efg ghi`
should return true, as `abc` is friend with `cde`, which is friend with `efg`, which is friend with `ghi` : all users are related.

`abc cde fgh hij`
should return false, as for example `abc` and `fgh` cannot be related through a friendship chain.

`abc`
should return true, as we cannot find in that list two unrelated users.

**Input**

- You can read the name list in any convenient format for your language.
- You can assume all the names are lowercase and use only the characters `a-z`.
- You don't need to handle the empty list, any result (true, false, program crash) is acceptable for it.

Comment: We've had transitive closure questions before ([1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69926/62131), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8647/62131)). This may be different enough to run, though (especially because the format increases the chance of a regex solution doing well), although it's particularly close to my second link there. I'd recommend the use of the [tag:graph-theory] tag, though, as it's clearly heavily *related* to the other transitive closure questions.

Comment: @ais523 yes that's almost same than http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/determine-number-of-unconnected-components... will not post then

Answer (score 2):

## Smallest integer divisible by 2..n

Given an integer n, output the smallest integer divisible by 2,3,4,...,n inclusive.

**Example**

2520 is divisible by every integer from 2 to 10.

**Scoring**

Shortest code in bytes wins.

**Sandbox**

- Dup?
- Better Wording?
- Restrictions/Rules?

Comment: So just `lcm(2..n)`?

Comment: you're right. would be marked as dup I guess :D

Comment: Actually, I don't think there's been challenges exactly like this before. I wouldn't call it a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

### Compare string repetitiveness [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given two strings, decide which one is more repetitive. This is the string whose most common character appears more often in it. If these are equal, then tiebreak by counting their respective second most common characters, and so on. Once a string's distinct characters have been exhausted, all further counts are zero.

Give one consistent output if the first string is more repetitive, and a different consistent output if the second one is. You will never be given a complete tie.

You may assume input strings will be non-empty and use only ASCII characters.

**Scoring:** Your code's score is its repetitiveness, with comparing lower being better. Put in your header the counts of the top 3 most common characters, and the full frequency list in your body.

**Test cases:**

TODO

Comment: additional tie break is probably just timing (of the post, not the programs computations)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon I was thinking alphabetical order (in the code page). Maybe that's interesting to optimize? If not, yes, I'll make it earlier post as standard.

Comment: A somewhat meatier task might be good, otherwise golfing languages might easily score 1 without even trying. Otherwise, I do think this scoring mechanism could be interesting.

Comment: Maybe you could use order-0 entropy. calculate it and the score is your own entropy?

Comment: I can't edit, so: "alternative is too have" -> "alternative is to have". To make the task harder, how about, when counting a specific letter, you start with the original string, but then each time it's found, the string you're going through is shifted by one through the Caesar cipher?

Comment: I think I prefer it less-meaty.  It presents it as an interesting scoring mechanism to main, and since languages don't compete against each other, I'd be rather interested in how well non-golfing languages fair.

Comment: I think I like this version better, as it isn't quite so easy for golfing languages while not being out of reach for some esoteric languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Normal quine, weird quine

> **Note**: This Sandbox entry has a fairly long history, and is basically an attempt to produce a challenge inspired by [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/triplegolf-not-only-the-source-code-length-counts#comment12232_5852), but that's immune to wilful misinterpretation (or misunderstanding) of what counts as an error in order to trivialise the question.

### Background

In the world of programming languages, there are lots of different ways to produce output on the usual output streams. Most languages have a way to print a string intentionally, called `print`, `write`, or something like that. Sometimes you can even just leave a value to be printed implicitly. Most languages also have situations in which the implementation interjects with its own output, e.g. warnings produced during the compile. We'll call this *weird output*.

### Task

For each method of output to standard output or standard error in a programming language, consider how much of that output is under the programmer's control and thus can contain arbitrary text (e.g. specified as a parameter, part of the program's filename, taken from a variable that can be assigned to, or the like), as opposed to being a single possibility (or a finite set of possibilities) hardcoded into the interpreter. We'll call this output method *normal* if no more than 3 bytes are outside the programmer's control; and *weird* if there are 4 or more hardcoded bytes that the programmer cannot control.

In this challenge, you need to write a **full program** that's a [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) variant, obeying the [proper quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/62131). Specifically, after performing the entire process of **building and running** the program (i.e. if there's a separate compile step required, its output counts too):

- All the output produced **on standard output and standard error** via normal output methods must be identical to the program's source code;
- All the output produced **on standard output and standard error** via weird output methods must also, separately, be identical to the program's source code.

In other words, the program is a quine in two different ways. You can think of this as being a quine that's also an [error quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36260/62131) (also known as a "Kimian quine"), except that the notion of "error" is restricted in order to avoid abuse (mechanisms which would let the program provide an arbitrary "error message" count as normal output, not weird output, on the above definition), but generalized to allow things like warnings, banners that the implementation prints as it loads, and other weird ways to produce output.

### Clarifications

- For the purpose of the proper quine definition, the fixed part of the output that's inherent in a weird output method is considered to not be encoded by the corresponding part of the program (even if that part of the program causes an error). As such, only the normal part of the quine can fail to be a proper quine.
- PPCG doesn't normally count output that's inherent to an implementation (such as compiler progress messages and fixed banners). This challenge is about handling that sort of thing, though, so such output is definitely relevant here (in addition to everything else on the standard output and error streams).
- Unlike in many challenges, the switches given to the compiler, and the program filename, are likely to be highly relevant in this challenge. Using an unusual build configuration may well be required to make the challenge possible, and as such is legal here; however, if you run the implementation in an unusual way, remember that PPCG rules charge a byte penalty for doing so (equal to the number of additional characters that you'd need to add on the command line over the shortest "normal" way to run a program), and thus you'll need to specify the size of the penalty in your post. (For example, if the interpreter you're using reads the program from a file, and has no particular restrictions on the filename, the shortest normal way to run the program would be from a file with a 1-character filename; thus, if you need a 100-character filename to make your program work, you'd incur a byte penalty of +99.)
- The compiler/interpreter version you use may well be relevant, so as part of your submission, please state a specific compiler or interpreter on which your program works, and which version is required. (For example, a C submission might state "C (gcc 6.2.0)" in the header.)
- Note that this task may not be possible in all languages. In the languages where it is, the easiest method will likely be to find an error or warning message for which it's possible to customize some subset of the text (via changing the name of something that gets quoted in the message; filenames are a common choice here, but not the only one). Obviously, if you could customize the entire thing, it wouldn't be weird output and thus wouldn't work. I'll be particularly impressed (and surprised) if someone finds a way to do this using *only* error and warning messages whose text is entirely fixed.

### Victory condition

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so an entry is considered to be better if it has a smaller byte count. As such, once you've got your program working at all, you want to optimize it to bring the number of bytes down as far as possible. (However, don't be discouraged if there's already a shorter entry, especially if it's in a different language; what we're really looking for here is to shorten a particular algorithm or idea behind a program as much as possible, but seeing multiple solutions in different languages or that rely on different principles is always worthwhile.)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

## Sandbox questions

This was moved here [from main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105753/error-or-warning-quine-thats-also-a-regular-quine) because many answerers seemed to disagree with everyone else as to what an error message was.

I've aimed to avoid the problem in this rewrite by focusing not on what is and isn't an error message, but rather on the amount of hardcoded content in the message. Is this likely to be interpreted the same way by everyone? Is it objective?

Also, should I edit the original challenge, or should I post it as a new challenge? Out of the two non-deleted answers, one will stay valid (although the explanation will end up somewhat out of context), the other will need to be deleted (although I consider it to be invalid under the original specification too, and thus arguably no changes are being made to which answers are correct).

Answer (score 2):

## Pseudoku Cops and Robbers King of the Hill

(I know that another user, @NathanMerrill, is proposing a similar contest.  I started playing with the idea for this type of contest independently yesterday, but have since chatted with in The Nineteenth Byte.  He is currently undecided on the type of puzzle to use and has some different ideas on how to evaluate participants' performance, so I feel comfortable proposing my idea as a separate challenge.)

Sudoku is a well-known logic puzzle.  It is a puzzle of four nines: nine rows of cells, nine columns of cells, nine 3x3 adjacent and distinct blocks of cells, and nine values that any cell can have.  A valid Sudoku arrangement or solution is one in which every row, cell, and block has all nine values exactly one time.  For example, consider the following valid solution:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|4 6 1|5 7 3|2 8 9|
|5 7 8|2 1 9|4 6 3|
|3 2 9|6 8 4|1 7 5|
+-----+-----+-----+
|9 8 4|7 6 2|3 5 1|
|7 5 6|3 4 1|9 2 8|
|2 1 3|9 5 8|7 4 6|
+-----+-----+-----+
|8 3 5|1 2 7|6 9 4|
|6 9 7|4 3 5|8 1 2|
|1 4 2|8 9 6|5 3 7|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

These are turned into puzzles by removing many of the values in the arrangement in such a way that all blanks are mirrored horizontally and vertically across the puzzle and so there is only one valid way to fill in the blanks to get a valid Sudoku solution.  For the above puzzle, this might look like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|4    |     |2 8  |
|  7  |  1  |    3|
|    9|    4|1    |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |7 6  |3 5 1|
|     |     |     |
|2 1 3|  5 8|     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|    5|1    |6    |
|6    |  3  |  1  |
|  4 2|     |    7|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Someone who wished to play this Sudoku puzzle would then use the information provided to find the original solution.

Sudoku has some interesting properties that allow it to be generalized to similar puzzles with different rules that are sometimes called "Pseudoku" (which is pronounced the same way as the actual puzzle, SOO-DOE-KOO, so please stop saying SOO-DOO-KOO).  For our purposes, we will make two differences.  First, it may be possible to generate harder puzzles by removing the restriction for symmetric removals.  The following is a valid puzzle by Sudoku rules, so why not allow it?

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|4   1|  7  |2    |
|5    |2   9|     |
|3    |  8  |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  8 4|7   2|    1|
|     |3   1|  2  |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |6    |
|  9 7|     |     |
|1    |     |5 3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Second, Sudoku's properties allow us to define games with different sizes.  You can define a Pseudoku game with a parameter `N` where the resulting board has `N^2` rows, `N^2` columns, `N^2` blocks of size `NxN`, and `N^2` values for each cell.  Standard Sudoku would be a Pseudoku variant with `N=3`.  So the following would be a valid Pseudoku(2) game:

```
+---+---+
|1  |   |
|   |  3|
+---+---+
|  1|4  |
|4  |   |
+---+---+
```

and an example Pseudoku(4) game:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|11         |      10  4| 1     9   | 2       16|
| 6     5   |   15  1   |    3     2|12  8      |
|10    13 14|         12| 5       15| 4     7   |
| 2  3      |    6    13|       8 11|    5    10|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 7 11 12  9|14        2|16  1  4   |           |
|           |   10  4   |          3|13    16 11|
| 4       10|   16    15|   12      |          6|
| 1 16  2   |11  3      |   10     8|           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3        2|       6   |13         | 5 14     1|
|    7      |          5|           |           |
|   13 14  4|12    16   |           | 8  9      |
|    5 16   |13     9   | 4     2  1|           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|14 12     7|           |   15     4|11     6   |
|    9      | 6         |11 16      |       3   |
|      11   | 8 13     1| 3 14      |    7      |
|13     8   | 7    11   | 2         |      15   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Since Sudoku is NP-complete, so is Pseudoku.  That means that it gets more difficult to solve a Pseudoku puzzle the larger `N` gets.  However, it can take more time to generate Pseudoku puzzles than it does to solve them, since the naive algorithm for generating a puzzle requires solving the puzzle each time a value is removed!  Solving Pseudoku puzzles is fun, but if it takes longer to generate them than it does to solve them, it becomes more work than play.

So help me out!  I propose a Cops and Robbers style King of the Hill.  The Cops will compete by writing programs to generate lots of Pseudoku puzzles to consume as much time as possible for solving, while the Robbers will compete by writing programs to solve Pseudoku puzzles to consume as little as time possible solving these puzzles.

I need some help ironing out the format, but here is what I have so far:

1. I will provide a Java framework for running the contest.  This framework will connect to clients by TCP/IP so contestants can choose whatever language they want to write their Cops and Robbers (so long as I can run them on my system).  I will also provide a basic Cop and Robber for these users to try out to see what sorts of times they take.  I will publish the times they generate on my system so contestants can estimate how their entries will run on my system.
2. I will give each Cop ten minutes to generate as many Pseudoku(`N>= 3`) puzzles as they can, but they should be able to generate at least Pseudoku(`N=4`) puzzles.  They can choose what sizes they want the puzzles to be, but they have to be valid with exactly one solution.  My server will naively check each one to guarantee their validity; any Cop that generates an invalid puzzle is disqualified.  I recommend configuring the Cop programs to be parameterized externally so that Robbers can test their code against basic Cop configurations, but then the Cops can send me secret, optimized configurations before the contest completes for their actual execution.  I will provide a couple days after the deadline ends for conferring with the Cop programmers if their settings do not work as expected on my system.  Cops should generate different puzzles every time with reasonable expectations; that means no spamming with the same puzzle repeatedly or reading pregenerated puzzles from a file system, Internet source, or internal cache.  In addition, I don't want to see a Cop that uses the same removal pattern for every puzzle (that may not guarantee valid puzzles, anyway).
3. Each Robber will be tested against each puzzle generated by the Cops.  The Robber will have to generate the correct solution for each puzzle as quickly as possible.  I will probably need to see some timings before I make a final decision, but each Robber will be capped with some amount of time to solve a puzzle (maybe an hour?) before the time-to-completion defaults to twice that cap.  These Robbers will be permitted to use any technique for solving the puzzles that my system supports except for packet sniffing.  I am on the fence as to whether the Robbers will be on an honor code to not study Cop code since I plan to have secret parameterizations anyway.
4. All the times for all the puzzles will be sorted from least to greatest and then assigned an index as one would in a Mann-Whitney U test.  Each Cop and Robber will be scored using the sum of the indices of their contributions: Cops for the times the Robbers spent solving their puzzzles, and Robbers for the times they spent solving puzzles.  The winning Cop will have the highest sum and the winning Robber the lowest.  Cop ties will be broken first by the average time required to solve one of its problems (more is better), then by the number of puzzles generated (more is better), then by the name I deem cooler (here's hoping that doesn't happen).  Robber ties will be broken first by the average time spent solving puzzles, then by the sum of the time, then by the standard deviation, then by the cooler name.
5. This scoring scheme poses an interesting challenge to Cops: balancing the size of the problems (and the likely amount of time needed to solve them) against the number of problems generated.  A Cop that generates only one puzzle that no Robber can solve in the time limit is likely to lose to another Cop that generates many moderate problems.  Similarly, a Cop that spams many small problems is likely to be beaten by another Cop that generates fewer problems of larger sizes.  Since the official contest configurations should be kept secret until the contest starts, other Cops can study the other programs to try to determine what their opponents are likely to do and plan accordingly.

I am interested in any and all feedback that the community might have about this challenge.

Comment: I pronounce Pseudoku as SOO-do-ku and Sudoku as soo-DO-ku, to align with the pronunciation of Pseudo.

Comment: I don't know if you'll get a lot of submissions. Sudoku is a bit difficult to program. Also, TCP-IP is not something people are used to using for their submissions.

Comment: It is?  Well, part of what I am looking for is whether people would participate.  I would need at a minimum two Cops and two Robbers or there is no point.  Could people comment saying whether they would play and whether they would play as a Cop, a Robber, or both?

Comment: The scoring system you've chosen adds a large incentive to submit a huge number of programs that are almost identical to your own submission but slightly worse. This means that if some opposing programs generate some puzzles that are harder than yours and some puzzles that are easier (which is likely), you'll push the easy ones right down the leaderboard, making your programs look better in comparison.

Comment: Good point.  This can be resolved by a "one-submission-per-category" rule.

Comment: If you want, I have some code that can help you communicate with submissions (over standard in/out).  However, I think the best solution is to run the cops' submission and kill it after 10 minutes.  They should write each sudoku puzzle as a file, which you would then read..  I also wouldn't worry about automated checking to see if the puzzles are valid.  I generally assume good faith in these types of challenges, unless it becomes an issue.

Comment: Re: validation... there's a problem here.  For it to make any sense, I would need to have at least as good a solver as the best Robber entry, in which case someone would just copy mine in a faster language than Java.  I think I would still require a unit testing protocol where I pass solutions to the Cops, the Cops return problems, and then I validate that they sent unique puzzles.

Comment: Re: standard input/output versus sockets... I don't get the aversion to network programming.  I used TCP in my Speed Clue contest a couple years ago, and it worked great (though I admittedly had few entries).  So long as I guarantee an environment for the contest (probably Linux), even C/C++ developers can write code with platform-specific libraries if they wish.  Using networking also allows a good method for timing responses: I start the clock once I get the ACK after sending a command, and I stop the clock after I ACK that I received a response.  File dumping makes timing Cops difficult.

Comment: 1. I don't think you've taken account of how badly things scale. It's easy to spit out valid pseudokus for `N=100`; validating them in a reasonable time requires supporting every rule which the cop knows. 2. The stuff about secret parameterisations doesn't really make sense to me. Taken to extremes, that could mean that we make the actual generation code the "parameterisation" and the cop "program" is just an eval. 3. The cop/robber setup means there's inherently a submission deadline. That's generally a bad thing, but even more so with something which can get extremely complicated.

Answer (score 2):

## broken keyboard workaround

|nspired by [BASTA´s song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXcSzPH73s) and memories from earlier work:

Your keyboard is broken but there is some urgent work you have to complete; you have no back^up hardware - and the shops are closed so you can´t buy a new keyboard!

All you have left to work with is your mouse.

6iven two texts as input (the one you have and the one you want to have), create a program or function that tells you the cut, copy&paste actions that will turn the one text into the other.

Using the mouse is strenuous, so you don´t want too many cut/copy/paste actions. Keep your output as short as possible.

Remember: Your keyboard is broken = you can´t use any characters in your code that you don't have ~ you must get alon9 with those that are provided in th1s {["te%t"]}. For7unately your keyboard 7ook qu17e a wh1le 7o bre4k down c0mpletely 4nd y0u used numb3rs 4nd sp3c*4l ch@r$ t0 r3pl@c3 br0k3n l3773r$; $0 y0u $h0uld h@v3 m0$7 0f 7h3m @v@*l@bl3.

Also, you don´t want to do too much C&P to cre8 your code, so keep that as short as possible, too.

---

- You can assume that the second text contains no characters that are not present in the first text.
- You can pick any input format and method that is convenient for you; but the output format should match that. (e.g. if you take input from files, output should also go to a file).

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

**NOTES**

Note that the challenge description contains all letters and digits except `j` and `z`. If you absolutely need them: they are hidden in the YouTube link. (I didn´t check for upper/lower case though.)

Curlys, brackets, braces, single and double quotes and all operators I could think of are there, so the challenge should be fine for most languages that use printable ASCII.

Still trying to find a more fluent way to include curlys, brackets, double quotes and circumflex, though.

I thought there was a tag [string-manipulation]; but couldn´t find it in the list.

I think about dropping the "output method should match input method" restriction.

Comment: Try `[tag:code-golf]` and `[tag:restricted-source]`

Comment: The part of your question with weird characters in it is a bit hard to read. Maybe tone it down a bit. Also, some examples would be helpful for understanding the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Find B1nar0 Solutions

B1nar0 puzzle is a paper and pencil game with 0 and 1. The goal is to fill the grid accoring to 3 rules :

1. No more than 2 consecutive 0s or 1s
2. Each row/column has half 0s and half 1s
3. No identical row/columns

Example :

[[image: 1]]

- A is 0 according to rule 1
- B is 1 according to rule 1
- C is 0 according to rule 2
- D is 1 according to rule 2
- etc.

Edit : Grids are square grids of even size (4, 6, 8, 10, 12 or 16 are usual sizes).

**Input** : Any binary grid (array or string) with `0`,`1` and any other character you want for empty cells.

**Output** : Same format as input but filled with a correct grid.

**Test case** (see GIF)

```
0 11
  0 
 0  
1 1
```

Comment: Are the grid dimensions always 4x4 ?

Comment: Non, any even number should fit, generally 4-6-8-10-12 or 16 games.

Comment: Nice challenge, but I suggest you add some test cases for the larger grid sizes too. Also, may we assume that we will get input that makes it possible to solve the puzzle? For instance not: [[1,1,1, ],[ , , , ],[ , , , ],[ , , , ]]. Can we assume that there will only be one valid solution? For instance, not an empty grid.

Comment: Also, the 6x6 test case is a lot harder than the 4x4. The 4x4 can be solved going through the matrix checking the different rules one after the other. To solve the 6x6 grid you need an algorithm that's a lot more sophisticated. Do you require that the program should be able to solve any input, regardless of the difficulty. Even if it requires brute-forcing the solution (which may take a loong time for a 16x16 matrix

Comment: Then you should add a few 10x10, 12x12 and 16x16 test cases (with solutions). Requiring that submissions can solve all possible boards regardless of difficulty makes this a really hard challenge. You should also impose a time limit. Otherwise I can just write a script that checks all possible combinations and claim that it will eventually find the right solution

Comment: I added the comments I had on the post when it was on main. Some of them are a bit out of context now, but I guess you remember what they're about. :)

Comment: Nice challenge, but I suggest you add some test cases for the larger grid sizes too. Also, may we assume that we will get input that makes it possible to solve the puzzle? For instance not: [[1,1,1, ],[ , , , ],[ , , , ],[ , , , ]]. Can we assume that there will only be one valid solution? For instance, not an empty grid

Answer (score 2):

### Enthusiastically Russianify a String

Greetings Comrades,

Many of you may have interacted with people from Russia on the internet at some point, and a subset of you may have noticed the slightly odd method they have of expressing themselves.

e.g. `деинсталляция игра нуб)))` - (forgive the google translate)

where the `)))` are added for emphasis on the previous statement, I have been working on a theory that the ratio of `)`'s to the rest of the string is directly proportional to the amount of implied emphasis, however I oftentimes find it difficult to compute the ratio on the fly, as I am also trying to cope with a slew of abuse, so I would like the shortest possible code to help me calculate what the resulting string should be, for a value of enthusiasm between 0 and 500%, given the original, unenthusiastic string, this will aid my research greatly as i will not have to type out bulky scripts every time I wish to test my hypothesis.

so, the challenge:

write a full program or function, which, provided two arguments, a string of unknown length, and a number, in either integer format (between 0 and 500) or in decimal format (between 0 and 5, with 2 points of accuracy) will

- return the original string, suffixed with a number of `)`'s
- the number will be the calculated as a ratio of the input number to the string length.
- so if the number 200, or 2.00 was provided, 200% of the string must be suffixed as `)`'s
- the number of brackets rounded to in decimal situations does not matter.
- script is required to support Printable ASCII characters.
- only has to support one input number format, of your choice.

examples:

```
"codegolf" 125      = codegolf))))))))
"codegolf" 75       = codegolf))))))
"noob team omg" 0.5 = noob team omg))))))
"hi" 4.99           = hi!)))))))))))))))
```

example code (powershell) (with decimal input):

```
Function Get-RussianString ([string]$InputStr,[decimal]$Ratio){
    $StrLen = $InputStr.Length
    $SuffixCount = $StrLen * $Ratio
    $Suffix = [string]::New(")",$SuffixCount)
    return $InputStr + $Suffix
}

Get-RussianString "codegolf" 0.5
codegolf))))
```

this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

---

This is my first challenge, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Privyet tovarisch, but challenges on PPCG need an objective winning criterion (eg [tag:code-golf] for shortest code)

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg - apologies this is code-golf, I included a mention of it in the 'background' block `shortest possible code` i'll include the tag now though.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork the minimum character set would be that, full Cyrillic alphabet support would be ideal, but I decided to simplify that aspect as much as possible, I could change it to the full ASCII set or otherwise if you believe it would be of benefit? - i'll include space as a default charachter, and remove the ! in the examples for now though.

Comment: Restricting the input to ["Printable ASCII"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5866/42963) would probably be sufficient.

Comment: If anything that's actually more understandable - i'll edit that in now, thanks!

Comment: Please edit the answer down to a hyperlink to the posted answer on the main site and delete it now that it is posted.

Answer (score 2):

> **Anyone who would like may post this challenge to main.** Just give credit to [@Lordofdark](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53198/lord-of-dark).

## How long will I sleep

You need to go to bed, but what you need more is to know how long you will sleep until your alarm rings.

### Your task

Write a program or function that takes a time (hours and minutes) as input, and outputs the number of hours and minutes until the next occurence of this time.

### Rules

- In this challenge every clock in 24h format.
- You must always get the current time for the same timezone; you can assume the input is in this timezone

#### Input

The input time must be in **hours and minutes** in any convenient **24h format** for your language.
Hours and minutes must always be separated by at least one character

Valid inputs for 8h30:
`"8h30"`
`8H30M`
`8,30`
`8 30`
`[8,30]`
...

Invalid inputs for 8h30:
`8.5`
`830`
`510min`

#### Ouptut

The output is the difference between current time and the next occurrence of the input time (it can only be today or tomorrow).

The same formatting rules apply : hours and minutes separated by at least one character an in 24h format.

Note that the output will always be between `0h00` and `23h59`

### Examples :

If it is currently 20h10 :

```
7h30 -> 11h20m
20h -> 23h50m
21h -> 0h50m
```

### Challenge

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are prohibited

Comment: This is my first challenge so I'm not sure about the I/O rules

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! :) Your challenge seems fine, though I recommend specifying that you should use a 24h clock earlier in the post. Aside from that, the "minutes are always two figures" part is a bit odd. Does that mean that if I used the format `[8, 30]` I would then have to return `[8, 05]`? Personally I would recommend just saying that hours and minutes have to be separate, as it is simpler and would require less space to show.

Comment: What timezone is the input and the current time? Do we assume UTC? What happens if a language can't get the current time?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman You are right I removed the 2 figures condition, and I specified at the beginning the 24h format.

Comment: @Artyer I guess I should add a condition about input and current being in the same timezone. Something like "You must always get the current time for the same timezone; you can assume the input is in this timezone". What do you think I could do for  language without access to current time ?

Comment: @Lordofdark in general, it's good to not exclude challenges for arbitrary reasons, but in this case there's a *very good* reason for certain languages to not be allowed. If it can't get the time, it can't compete.

Comment: Are multi-character separators allowed in the input format (e.g. `8 hours 30 minutes`)? They probably shouldn't be, or people may well figure out a way to put their entire program in the separators and thus get a score of 0 (or however many bytes `eval` is in their language).

Comment: @Lordofdark can I adopt this abandoned challenge?

Comment: @programmer5000 yes you can. Sorry I totally forgot about this

Answer (score 2):

## How extreme can a letter be?

### Challenge

Write a function or program that accepts a rectangular grid of letters (`A`-`Z`) as input, and provides an output as follows:

- If the grid contains repeated letters, output the maximum rectilinear distance between two positions on the grid covered by the same letter.
- If every letter in the grid is unique, output 0.

### Example

Given this grid:

```
AEBZWZSFUS
XWHZITHJNN
OQDSLRZFCW
KOMBQQVAGT
FAGIBOZZAX
MECUIFYKYB
UGURYVFHAT
IICZSFMUTC
JPPHXNXSEW
TSUTJMVCNI
```

...your output should be 17.  This is the rectilinear distance between the `S` on the top right corner and the `S` on the bottom row.

### Rules

This is code golf; shortest code in bytes wins.  Standard loopholes disallowed.

#### Formatting

- Input via standard input, ordered collections (list/array/etc) of strings, or two dimensional array/list/etc of characters is allowed.
- Output via return value, exit code, or standard output is allowed.

#### Input guarantees

(If the input doesn't comply with these, you don't have to handle it)

- The input is a rectangular grid.
- Every position on the grid is an upper case letter.
- The grid will be at least 2 characters wide.
- The grid will be at least 2 characters tall.
- The grid will be no wider than 98 characters.
- The grid will be no taller than 98 characters.

#### Output restriction

- Your output should be a single non-negative number indicating the request value.

### Test Cases

```
IXHNBFJFQLQGKEWVCXCX
DVBRMDCGENVDYWDJLADY
FPMTNQHOFPPURUMZXPEJ
ZLOIFSYPKLXFOYOIKUMJ
LKZOSZWWKLWLFZBQQLYJ
-> 19

ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
OPQRSTU
-> 0

DSMPAHNP
JUWYNWOE
AIUOCIPY
MHODAXVG
NFETRIWH
YDQYVLZL
LDTZBYER
JEXPFRDR
-> 13

ZYXWVUTSRQPO
TSRQPOZYXWVU
NMLKGIHGFEDC
HGFEDCNMLKGI
-> 7

QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
-> 40
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

Answer (score 2):

### Animate the text in your terminal

**The goal**

The goal is to "animate" the string "Hello world" in your output so that each character gets capitalised after each other.

Your program can exit after each letter has been capitalised.

For example;

```
# Iteration 1
Hello world

# Iteration 2
hEllo world

# Iteration 3
heLlo world

# Iteration 4
helLo world

# Iteration 5
hellO world

# Iteration 5
hello world

# Iteration 6
hello World

# Iteration 7
hello wOrld

# Iteration 8
hello woRld

# Iteration 9
hello worLd

# Iteration 10
hello worlD
```

**Input**

No input is required, but "Hello world" must be the string that is "animated".

**Output**

The string "Hello world" must be animated. The output must be as 1 line to create a sort of wave animation. Example gif;

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/be12b693063b463540c5bf1f03d2454a.gif]

<sup>I saw this on a metasploit youtube video and thought the effect was pretty cool, which is where I recorded the gif from, so it's a little laggy, but I hope it illustrates the output fine</sup>

This is code-golf, lowest byte-count will be deemed the winner.

Comment: I think that you should make it that you take input and animate that.

Answer (score 2):

## Packing Primes for Posterity

## Introduction

You've calculated which of the first `n` numbers are prime, and want to save your achievement for all future generations. Unfortunately, you're broke, and want to minimize storage costs (you'll be paying them forever, after all.)

You need to determine the best way to pack all of the primes `<=n` and still be able to answer the question "is `p` prime?" in `O(1)` time.

## Challenge

A submission to this challenge must include both a `compress` algorithm and an `isPrime` algorithm.

#### compress

Input: `n` -- the number that you have checked prime-hood through.

Output: Bytes to feed into your `isPrime` algorithm.

#### isPrime

Input: The output of your compression algorithm, and an integer `i >= 0`. `i` is guaranteed to be `<= n`.

Output: `True` if `i` is prime, otherwise `False`.

This algorithm *must* run in O(1).

The winner of this challenge is the (compression, isPrime) pair that is

- Correct
- Has the best compression ratio, as determined by the average compression ratio for

  > n in {10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9}

as compared to the naive solution below.

Consider the following solution in Python:

```
def compress(n):
    # simple sieve of Eratosthenes. Note: this is not a 
    # prime generation challenge; a list of the first 
    # billion numbers will be provided in this format.
    primes = [1] * (n + 1)
    primes[0] = 0
    primes[1] = 0
    upper_bound = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    for i in range(2, upper_bound):
        factor = i
        if not primes[factor]:
            continue
        factor += i
        while factor <= n:
            primes[factor] = 0
            factor += i
    primePackStr = ''.join(str(i) for i in primes)
    return primePackStr

def isPrime(compressed, i):
    return compressed[i] == '1'
```

## Example Input and Output

Input to `compress`:

> 20

Output:

> "001101010001010001010"

Input to `isPrime`:

> ("001101010001010001010", 13)

Output:

> True

## Notes

- This is not a prime generation challenge. The `compress` executable can assume that there is a file called `primes.txt` in the same directory that contains the first billion numbers in the format `s[i] = 1` if i is prime, 0 otherwise. (Zero-indexed)
- Naturally, the `isPrime` executable cannot make use of this file.
- The `isPrime` executable must not hardcode any primes.
- Please provide instructions on how to compile/run your code on either OSX 10.12 or Ubuntu 16.04, if it's not obvious.
- This is *not* a code golf challenge. Any length of code is fine, as long as `isPrime` doesn't attempt to cheat.

## Notes for sandbox

- I'll include a link to a downloadable primes.txt
- Any thoughts on a better restriction than "The `isPrime` executable must not hardcode any primes?"
- Should I test on random values of `n` instead?
- thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting idea, and I hope it can be made to work, but it does have a big problem in the subtlety of what you mean by saying that isPrime must run in O(1) time. Interpreted with maximum pedantry, it's impossible because O(1) time isn't sufficient to read `i` from the input, even assuming random access to the input (which some key models of computation don't, and many interpreters won't give you).

Comment: If you instead restrict answers to accessing a fixed (independent of `n` and of the length of the compressed text) number of bytes of the compressed text and doing a fixed (independent of `n` and `i`) amount of processing on them, you're pretty much killing the challenge because the only feasible compression will be bit-packing with a wheel and the competition will just be how big to make the wheel.

Comment: In particular, a wheel size of 10^9 would trivialise the challenge.

Comment: As far as your first comment goes, I could clarify to say that isPrime can assume that the entire output of `compress` is already in memory - or that isPrime may be called many times, with different `i` but the same `compressed` and it only has to be amortized O(1). Unfortunately, you're totally right about the prime wheel - though the idea is that the algorithm would work for arbitrary values of n, not just up to 10^9.

Comment: Maybe I could entirely remove the isPrime in O(1) restriction and simply make this a challenge about the most efficient compression algorithm for prime numbers. (Allowing arbitrary compression.) @PeterTaylor

Comment: If you do that then everyone will compress the list to 0 bytes unless you fix the decompression. A variant which might work is to ditch `isPrime` and say that the output of `compress` will be passed through `zcat | sort -n` so that the challenge is finding a good ordering of the primes which exploits Lempel-Ziv behaviour.

Comment: That might be interesting, though I'd need to add some sort of polynomial time restriction - you could theoretically test all O((n/(log n))!) orderings of primes `<= n` otherwise. I'm going to abandon this for now, but may come back eventually if I have an epiphany. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a really interesting idea, and I hope you can come up with a way to make it work successfully.

Answer (score 2):

**Challenge about loudly interjecting in a courtroom**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

One of the most important things about being a courtroom lawyer is loudly interjecting before you make your point. In this challenge, we're going to edit a typical courtroom transcript to include these interjections.

Any lawyer (and in fact, any character at all in the transcript), uses these rules to interject:

> 1. Use an interjection when the character who is speaking changes to you.

Take the following example:

```
SAHWIT: I remember the time I found the body exactly.
SAHWIT: It was 1 P.M.
PHOENIX: Frankly, I find that hard to believe!
PHOENIX: Your statement directly contradicts the autopsy report.
```

There is one change in speaker, so an interjection will be added in at that point like this:

```
SAHWIT: I remember the time I found the body exactly.
SAHWIT: It was 1 P.M.
PHOENIX: Hold it! Frankly, I find that hard to believe!
PHOENIX: Your statement directly contradicts the autopsy report.
```

> 2. Use **Hold it!** if the previous statement ends with a single full-stop or exclamation mark, **Take that!** if the previous statement ends with an elipses (...), and **Objection!** if the previous statement ends with a question mark.

For instance:

```
JUDGE: What evidence proves the clock is running slow?
PHOENIX: The victim had just returned from abroad the day before the murder.
PHOENIX: The time difference between here and Paris is 9 hours!
PAYNE: But modern day clocks automatically adjust for time zones...
PHOENIX: This is an antique!
```

Becomes:

```
JUDGE: What evidence proves the clock is running slow?
PHOENIX: Objection! The victim had just returned from abroad the day before the murder.
PHOENIX: The time difference between here and Paris is 9 hours!
PAYNE: Hold it! But modern day clocks automatically adjust for time zones...
PHOENIX: Take that! This is an antique!
```

That's about it. I'll write some longer test cases a bit later. This challenge is probably Retina-bait to be honest.

Comment: This challenge might work better if the interjections made more sense in context. For example, "Objection!" likely works best after questions (as most objections in an actual court case are to try to invalidate a question that fails to follow the rules).

Answer (score 2):

## Tell me my vocabulary words! [Donated.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13504/64159)

When taking textbook notes, I need to write down the vocabulary words and their definition. So your task is to write some code that will give me the vocabulary words and their definitions!

Vocabulary words are detonated with a `*` on both sides of them, like this: Sentences are `.`-delimited, meaning that after every `.` a new sentence starts. An example of a valid sentence would be: `This sentence has a *vocab word* in it.` The vocab word in the sentence is 'vocab word'.

**Input:** A string of text with some words marked with asterisks. Only valid inputs will be provided, meaning that only sentences with exactly two asterisks inside of them, and there is something between the asterisks.

**Output:** A list or delimited string where each item is in the following format: `Vocabulary word: sentence`. The `Vocabulary word` is the vocab word found in the sentence. The sentence must be the one with the emboldened vocabulary word in it. If there is any whitespace other than the  s separating the words, it needs to be stripped.

**Test cases:**

```
Input: *Alan Turing* invented the Turing machine. A *Turing machine* is a machine that follows simple rules, but is capable of any computation.

Output: *Alan Turing*: *Alan Turing* invented the Turing machine.
        *Turing machine": A *Turing machine* is a machine that follows simple rules, but is capable of any computation.

Input: What is code-golf? *Code-golf* is the best site on the SE network. But what is SE, you ask? *SE* is a group of Q&A sites, with a system to prevent bad posts.

Output: *Code-golf*: *Code-golf* is the best site on the SE network.
        *SE*: *SE* is a group of Q&A sites, with a system to prevent bad posts.
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: So split on '.' and then filter to strings containing a `*`? Or can there be asterisks which don't mark vocabulary words? Should we trim whitespace at the start and end of the sentences?

Comment: @PeterTaylor A string surrounded by `*` is a vocab word, like this: `*vocab word*`. You need to format the outputted sentence correctly, and trim whitespace. I will edit when I have more time.

Comment: Are the following valid inputs or not? a) `Unbalanced* asterisk`; b) `Empty ** vocabulary word`; c) `Vocabulary* word *has bad spacing`.

Comment: Only the last one is valid.

Comment: The latest wording "*only sentences with exactly two asterisks in them*" suggests that there's no need to filter: just split on `.`, trim, and prepend `Vocabulary word: ` to each sentence.

Answer (score 2):

## Garbled Phone Numbers

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (de)[cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher)

You know how you get a voicemail message and the person's connection wasn't great, and you're trying to figure out how to call them back, but you're not sure if that was a "5" or an "8" they said?

That's this challenge.

The good news is that the caller read off their number twice, but it's garbled in both places.

Your program should take input like this:

```
5551231234 / 5551231234
```

Where the first seven digits are the first time the phone number is said in the voice mail and the second set are the second time it's said.  Only...it'll look more like this:

```
555?AAA1_36? / 55?522_1?234
```

A digit followed by a question mark means that that's the best-guess for that digit (e.g. "5?" means "probably a 5, compare with repeat").  An underscore indicates a known missing digit, something too fuzzed by static to be deciphered at all.  Letters are just that: letters. Treat them as their respective digits (ABC -> 2, DEF ->3, HIJ -> 4, etc).

You can safely assume the following judgement calls:

```
5? / _     -> 5  //5 is the best guess we have, use it
5? / 4?    -> ?  //conflict
 5 / 4     -> ?  //conflict
5? / 4     -> 4  //solid information overrides possible value
 5 / 4?    -> 5  //solid information overrides possible value
 _ / _     -> ?  //no information available
```

Additionally you can assume that all inputs will contain ten-digit phone numbers, not including the question marks. Inputs that aren't ten digits (e.g. `1234567 / 1234567`) can either be treated as unsolvable (falsey output) or throw an error.

Output option A:
Output a truthy value indicating whether or not a given input can be resolved to a single valid ten-digit phone number.

Output option B:
If it can be parsed to a single valid ten-digit phone number, output the phone number. Otherwise output some form of error indication (e.g. -1, false, empty line).

Shortest wins, as per usual.

[Sample inputs]

Comment: I'm not sure what your intended meaning for letters is. If it's just A=1,B=2,C=3... then they're a bit pointless and weird in this context. 
You should also probably choose only one between option A and option B before posting (I vote for B).

Comment: @Leo Letters as they appear on a dial pad: A,B,C = 1, DEF = 2, GHI = 3, etc.

Comment: You need an explicit mapping for letter→number. Most phones I've seen map A/B/C to 2 (apparently they follow [this international standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.161)).

Comment: @ais523 Whoops, that's what I get for posting late at night just before bed, then making the comment gia tablet at a rest stop somewhere in western Pennsylvania, 6 hours from home.

Comment: I think you should omit 'output option A' and just keep B; B includes A pretty much.

Comment: @officialaimm I think that's the beret idea, yes. There were a mess of ideas running around in my head, such as scoring based on a given input list,  but never congealed well enough to make it to paper. A and B were the only two that did.

Comment: Any other comments before I start generating some inputs and posting it?

Answer (score 2):

## Write a "21" game in exactly 21 characters [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)

### Challenge

You must write a program which implements the following algorithm:

```
Let x = 0
Let y = truthy value
while (y is not falsy AND x <= 21) do:
  Let x = x + a uniform random number from {1,2,3,...,11}
  Output the value of x
  Input a value of y from the user (you may assume input is valid)
Output the value of x
```

(You do not have to follow the pseudocode exactly. For example, if your language happens to initialise variables to a truthy value automatically, you don't have to include the `y:=TRUE` line. Similarly, you don't have to use a while loop. The important thing is that it repeatedly takes user input until either x exceeds 21 or the user chooses to stop, and it outputs the current value of x after each user input.)

### Score

Let n be the length of the shortest program which meets the spec which can be obtained by deleting 0 or more characters from your code. Then your score is:

```
- 500            if n > 21
- 1 + (n-21)^2   if n < 21
```

The winner in each language is the program with the lowest score.

### Questions

- Is this a resonable idea? I can't find similar challenges, so maybe there is a problem with ones like this? (Trivial solutions etc.)
- Is the specification too complicated (maybe more languages could enter if it was a simpler algorithm, for example just taking user input once?)

Comment: This victory condition is [tag:code-shuffleboard]. I don't think it adds much over just doing golf, though; it's normally fairly easy to pad out a program in a way that can't be fooled via simple character deletion. (Also, I suspect 21 characters isn't enough in most languages, although golfing languages should be able to beat that; it'll be interesting to see whether some of the terser practical languages can.)

Answer (score 2):

## Tetris Programming

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetris)

### The Task

Your program or function should take as input one character from the set `IJLOSTZ`, which represents one of the seven tetrominos as usual:

```
I  J   L   O   S    T    Z

#   #  #   ##   ##  ###  ##
#   #  #   ##  ##    #    ## 
#  ##  ##
#
```

You should output the number of shapes which are equivalent to this tetromino up to rotation. For example, the `I` only has two arrangements, horizontal and vertical, whereas the `J` has four different orientations. The `O` looks the same no matter how you rotate it, so there's only one shape. Here all possible input/output pairs:

```
I  2
J  4
L  4
O  1
S  2
T  4
Z  2
```

### The Source Code

The main part of this challenge is the source code restriction:

- You may choose either linefeeds (LF, 0x0A), carriage returns (CR, 0x0D) or LR-CR pairs to represent newlines in your code (consistently). These split the source code into a 2D grid of lines (which aren't necessarily the same length).
- This 2D grid must be completely made up of tetrominos where all 4 characters in each tetromino must be the same. For example, this would be a valid program:

  ```
  aaa
  bba
  cbddd
  cbd
  c
  c

  eeee
  ```

  Note that the individual characters don't necessarily need to be distinct, so there may be larger connected regions of the same character, as long as this region can be segmented into non-overlapping tetrominos. Also note that this restriction also applies to spaces, so the following is not a valid program, because the two spaces don't form a tetromino.:

  ```
    x
  xxx
  ```

### The Score

For each of the seven tetrominos count how often it appears in your source code. Your score is the maximum of these seven values.

That means you don't want to make up your code entirely of `I`s but instead try to use about the same number of each of them to keep the maximum of the seven values down.

### The Small Print

You may either write [a programs or a functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the [standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output, as usual. Note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/) are forbidden by default.

Comment: It strikes me that most solutions are going to put most of the code in a comment, and it wouldn't surprise me if a score of 1 were achievable in some languages. Do you consider that reasonable?

Comment: @ais523 I'm not sure about the task yet. It's hard to find something that isn't too hard for the restriction to become a pain but that is intricate enough to allow people to use several parts of a tetromino.

Answer (score 2):

So I've been puzzling over the best way to present this idea I had, so this will probably need a *lot* of help.  I am open to completely reworking the challenge, but this is the best polish I've managed to figure out so far.

At work I have to secure my laptop with one of those 4-digit cable locks and it occurred to me that there was a puzzle here: figuring out the combination by looking at the typical behavior of setting the lock: never allowing any given wheel to "rest" on its unlocked value.  e.g. if the combination is `1234` then never walking away with a 1 in the first position, a 2 in the second, and so on (e.g. `1111` would not be considered locked, but `2111` would be).  Or possibly by not letting *any* digit of the unlocked combination be visible (so even `2111` would be "bad" but `6789` would be ok...unless a transpose was *also* considered to be insufficiently random, however such choices are often up to the user of the lock). I also subsequently changed my behavior (not that I have any real risk of my laptop being stolen).

A standard challenge of "write some code that examines a series of locked values to determine the unlocked value, scoring by number of entries needed" is non-viable, as the sequence list would need to be carefully chosen such that there is a strictly known optimal solution (i.e. a minimum number of locked values), as finding a shortcut in that *specific* sequence might be possible, but invalid on another sequence.

Then the other night it occurred to me that it might be possible to do this as [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers): one side has to randomize their locks (albeit following a set of rules that allows exploitation), the other side has to break them open.  The downside being that it will be a *nightmare* to validate scores as there will be no easy way to pipe input and output back and forth between two programs running arbitrary languages.

I'm also not sure if there's enough room for freedom in designing the lock randomization code (i.e. interesting for the cop) for it to be plausibly crackable without resorting to brute force (an uninteresting challenge for the robber). Ostensibly the robber half *is* brute force, but it's guided in some manner towards a determinable value ("ah, I see, the first spindle is never set to `1` when locked, ergo the first digit in the code *must* be a `1`) rather than indeterminate ("ah, I see, *no* spindle is ever set to `1`, ergo there is a `1` somewhere in the code" -> 4 digits ^ 4 spindles -> 256 plausible values with further attempts gaining no new information).

---

## Combination Locks (Cops)

[image: 8585: Locked]

Your goal is to write a program that produces a 4 digit random number as a combination lock entry code.  Your program needs to keep this value a secret, but must produce output that is the result of the lock being locked and its tumblers spun, the value printed being the digits shown along the set row (`8585` in the above image).

Your program will then take input of a 4 digit code that is an attempt to unlock the lock.  If it is the correct value, output the number of attempts made and the seed value, otherwise print another randomized lock value.  Repeat until successfully unlocked.

Rules:

- Your program must have some way of setting the combination (for scoring), eg. providing a seed value for the random number generator (inputting the correct combination is allowed).
- All locked combinations must be considered random.  However:
- The nature of "random" is what is to be exploited here. Obviously you wouldn't want your random lock to actually remain unlocked after shuffling the dials!
- You may chose any rules by which to keep the lock locked, provided that it can be exploited. No outputting `0000` every iteration or cycling between predetermined sets (`1234`,`4567`,`7890`,`1234`). You're trying to emulate what appears to be smart behavior of a human being, not create an unbreakable lock.
- Every digit from 0-9 should be possible with some degree of uniformity. That is, if the correct combination is `1234` you are allowed to prevent `1` from showing up as the fist digit, but you may not prevent `1` from showing up in other positions.

  - Blanket removal of all four digits of the combination from all four columns reduces the problem to brute forcing 256 possible combinations.
  - Similarly, allowing a ban on a digit for *up to three* columns reduces it to brute force against 3136 possible combinations (banning *only* the combination digits from 3 columns is 81 possible combinations).  None of these are interesting challenges.
  - Entries shown to devolve to a brute force guessing will score based on the worst-case lucky guess (i.e. the number of attempts needed to identify the brute-force point, +1).
- If your language does not have a way to "wait for input" then....??? (requirements for fixed-seed randomness across multiple attempts, e.g. for a given combination and the same number of attempts made, the next output should be the same)
- Your program should store no data about attempts to break the lock or prior output values, the only data that may be stored are the `Random` instance (if needed), the correct combination, and number of attempts made.  Outputting an attempt value back out (intentionally) would be underhanded.

## Scoring

The ratio of your code's byte-length to the best (lowest) number of attempts needed by any robber against your lock.

---

## Combination Locks (Robbers)

[image: 8585: Locked]

Your goal is to exploit the non-pure-random nature of locked 4 digit combination lock. After all, no one leaves a portion of the correct code in the lock after they shuffle the wheels!

You are to write a program that attempts to deduce the correct combination for a given lock, given only a series of locked (incorrect) combinations.  Your program will read a single 4 digit number as the current state of the lock and produce a 4 digit number output as an attempt to unlock the lock.  If additional input is given, the attempt was unsuccessful.  Your program need not self-terminate (i.e. there is no requirement to take input telling your program that it was successful; ctrl-C interrupt is succificient).

As you are an accomplished thief, you know exactly how each lock gets randomized. You are to exploit the built-in rules to bypass the lock in the fewest number of attempts by looking for patterns in the lock's "output" and narrowing down the list of possible correct combinations.

- Locks will have a way to predetermine their combination (e.g. random seed or specific 4 digit combination). Your program may not know these values, they are used for scoring only. Remember the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default): hardcoding the output is disallowed.
- If a human is unable to find the solution with the data known at that the point of solving, the number of attempts will not count for scoring as it can be considered a lucky guess (arbitrary threshold: 10 or fewer attempts will be automatically assumed as such). This should be treated like a logic puzzle, not a slot machine.
- If your language of choice doesn't do "programs" it is acceptable to write a function taking in an array of inputs `[XXXX, AAAA, XXXX, BBBB, XXXX]` (where `XXXX` represents the combinations displayed on the lock, and `AAAA`/`BBBB` represents the prior attempts made) or similar.  Note that there will be one more value from the lock than values from attempts, as your function would be producing the paired half as its output.

  - Supplementary output to support ease of alternative input methods acceptable (e.g. a newline followed by the input array for the next iteration to be copy-pasted).

## Scoring

The ratio of your code's byte-length to the best (lowest) number of attempts needed top open any lock.

Comment: @Ilikemydog I browsed other cops and robbers questions while writing, scoring did not seem unusual. [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117319/47990) has scoring, so does [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109949/47990), and [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115036/47990) calls for short code (typical scoring method), while [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112300/47990) scores based on number of different cops entries cracked. However, that's not my main concern, *"I'm also not sure if there's enough room for freedom in designing a lock.."*

Comment: never mind then. I'll delete the comment. I'd like to give you some more feedback but I didn't follow some of it (mfny) and all I can say is have a +1

Comment: No feedback, except I've had this exact thought that a  code could be guessed by tracking where the lock was left set to when it was locked over time. Similar idea, but you actually fleshed it out.

Comment: @BLT That was pretty much where I'd been approaching from. Still not sure there's a *good* code challenge here, though. :\ Thanks for the look over!

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to find anything in my searches, but please let me know if this or something very similar has been done before.  Appreciate any feedback, first post in sandbox.

### Can I leave yet?

I'm bored at work, and want to know how close I am to being able to go home.  To represent this, I wish to know what percentage of work I have completed for the day.

**Inputs**

None - Current local/computer time shall be used

**Outputs**

Percentage of work completed for this day

- Formatted as either a percentage value or a decimal value: `0.57`, `.57`, `57%`, `57.0%`
- Output should be accurate to at least +/-0.5%.  Additional accuracy/digits are allowed.
- The work day is a total of 8 hours.
- Work starts at 08:00, and ends at 17:00.
- Lunch is between 12:00 and 13:00.  Working during lunch is forbidden, and thus should not count towards the percentage of work completed.
- Output should be correct during any time of day, including before work starts (0%) and after the work day ends (100%).

The response for a full 24 hour day is shown below:

[image: ResponseGraph]

**Valid Test Cases**

```
Time Ran     Output
03:55        0%
04:31        0.000
08:00        0
09:00        12.5%
11:31        44%
12:37        .5
16:30        0.94
21:08        100%
```

**Incorrect Test Cases**

```
09:00        12.5     (Interpreted as 1250%
11:31        43%      (Error of 0.9%)
12:37        .58      (Did not account for lunch)
16:30        0.9      (Error of 3.8%)
```

**Notes**

- I work 7 days a week 365 days a year; you do not need to check if it's a weekend, holiday, etc.
- I live in an area with no Daylight Savings Time, Leap Seconds, or any other confusing time-changing events.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count score wins.

Comment: Does no feedback mean it's perfect the way it is and I should post it?  Or it's so bad that nobody wants to touch it?

Comment: I think it's pretty solid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raindrops are falling on my... glasses?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/raindrops-are-falling-on-my-glasses)

Comment: So a minimum of 216 seconds runtime? Note that TIO times out after 60 seconds.

Comment: How many newlines are "enough"? May we assume a 5-lines screen?

Comment: @Adám is there anything you like in this post? And however large your screen is. If you want to reduce the size of the screen, feel free.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. This challenge is good. It just needed so tightening up. That's what the sandbox is for. Better get constructive criticism here than downvotes on the main site.

Comment: So, if one can choose screen size you may as well just specify that glasses (if not changed in-place or the screen is cleared) must be separated by a FormFeed or one or more newlines.

Comment: What about cursor movement with [terminfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html) (like `\e[10D\e[2A` to move 10 spaces left and 2 lines up)? The solution would only work in the terminal, but there it would certainly *look* as if the image stays the same (and would look way better than other approaches). Is this allowed?

Comment: @eush77 sure why not?

Comment: @RandomUser I guess it was just not clear to me from the statement.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when almost every space is at @ but some are at O? Locations are still chosen totally randomly, so the visible effect will be that almost nothing is happening?

Comment: @SteveBennett yes. It's an unfortunate side effect

Comment: You could change the behaviour so that rain never lands on @'s, although it's hard to implement this in a way that doesn't verge on infinite loops.

Answer (score 2):

## Range without Range Builtin

## Challenge

Given an integer `y` where `y > 0`, output a list of in some reasonable format that contains every integer in increasing order up to but not including `y`, without using any builtin that generates a range of any sort.

If your language has a feature whose specification uses a range, that is not allowed (for example, you cannot use the map quick in Jelly on a single integer because that maps over the range). You can assume that `y` will not exceed your program's capacity for integers, but it must be able to theoretically work on any integer given no memory, time, or otherwise language constraints.

A format is reasonable for a list `a = [a0, a1, ..., an]` if and only if there exists a string `x`, a string `y`, and a non-empty string `z` such that the output is `x + z.join(a) + y`.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: This seems extremely simple :P `for(i=0;i<y;i++)printf("%d ",i);`

Comment: @MDXF Yes, but there's a 4-byte solution in Jelly. :P

Comment: Which you have disallowed....

Comment: @MDXF No, there's a 1-byte solution that I disallowed. There's also a 2-byte solution which I disallowed with the rule about the specification backend. Hint: Iterating through a list or iterating like you did is permitted.

Comment: Ah, now I see. This would probably get 50 submissions in 10 minutes, have fun with the clogged inbox :P

Comment: @MDXF I don't mind :P

Comment: I don't think this question would be closed, but I have to voice my dislike for this challenge.  I am not a fan of banning builtins in the first place, I feel it has a number of issues.  My main problem is it is hard to enforce/judge when someone is using a builtin.  This challenge is going to take that and push it to its limits.  I feel that this for this question to work you would need a very solid definition of what a built in is and I don't think such a thing can be made.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thank you for your feedback. I will try to get a fully objective way to determine what a builtin is and if I can find one I will mention you again in a comment for your review, and if I can't then this challenge will probably die and be buried by the rest of the sandbox posts because I don't want bad challenges :P

Comment: I'd recommend posting this after adding a few rules - in what order do the integers need to be printed? What's the max value `y` can be? "In a list of some reasonable format" is a bit too broad IMO.

Comment: @MDXF I will clarify in the post, thanks.

Comment: @MDXF "in increasing order" I think I clarified.

Comment: Looks great! My last suggestion is to make it a bit more readable: The `# Challenge` right at the top doesn't really add anything. And I'd recommend splitting the paragraph in half, i.e. making `If your language has a feature whose specification uses a range...` its own paragraph.

Comment: @MDXF Yes, that makes it much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the `# Challenge` is the header of the actual question; the title won't be there in the actual post. :)

Answer (score 2):

## The alphabet - my way

Your pointy-haired boss gives you a list of words and tells you to sort them.  So you give him back a sorted list.  "Wrong!" he says.  "I want them sorted according to MY alphabet..."

## Challenge

Given a new ordering of the alphabet and a list of words, sort the words according to that new alphabet ordering.

The new ordering is given as a 26-character string, guaranteed to contain all letter of the alphabet exactly once, in lower case.

All words in the list of words will be made up of lower case letters only -- no capital letters or punctuation.  There will be no repeat words.

If there is a word in the list that is the prefix of another word, then the shorter (prefix) word should appear first in the sorting.  For example, "golf" should appear before "golfing".

## Examples

### Example 1

Input:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
apple
banana
currant
dragonfruit
elderberry
fejoia
```

Output:

```
elderberry
apple
dragonfruit
fejoia
currant
banana
```

### Example 2

Input:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
uranium
plutonium
uranus
pluto
polonium
```

Output:

```
uranus
uranium
polonium
pluto
plutonium
```

### Example 3

Input:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
four
score
and
seven
years
ago
```

Output:

```
ago
and
four
score
seven
years
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pluto`/`plutonium` be before `polonium`

Comment: No, because 'o' comes before 'l' in that alphabet.  Just like when you alphabetise using the standard alphabet, ties are broken by the alphabetical rank of subsequent letters.

Comment: Oh wait read `polonium` wrong sorry

Answer (score 2):

## [Print a shuffled deck of cards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/124565/68615)

Comment: What prevents me from outputting the cards in the same order every time? It's hard to specify randomness, as we've seen in other meta posts. You could say "I will run your program 100 times; no two outputs should be identical" since the probability of this happening is miniscule if the output is truly randomized.

Comment: I believe "all permutations must have an equal opportunity of being chosen" is what is usually used.

Comment: I don't think having to output the Unicode card characters adds anything to the challenge and the answers (except for bytes...).

Comment: All I see in my browser is a bunch of rectangles with diagonals.

Comment: @Dennis Install the Noto fonts.

Comment: "all permutations must have an equal opportunity of being chosen" is actually EXTREMELY difficult, the random number generators of most languages aren't up to that -- even making sure every combination can come up is quite tricky as you need 225 bits of randomness.

Comment: @programmer5000 It's already only a title

Comment: It should still be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

## Title

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

#### Challenge

In your language of choice, write 25 programs, functions, or snippets that output or return the integers 1 through 25, inclusive. However, the goal is to simultaneously minimize the number of distinct chars used and the length of the code.

#### Scoring

This is a variation on [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): If your 25 entries have **N** distinct characters and a total length of **L**, your score is **N × (L + N)**. **The submission with the lowest score wins.**

#### Example

Say the challenge only went up to 10, and your ten snippets were:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

That's 11 bytes total, and 10 distinct chars; therefore, your final score would be **10 × (11 + 10) = 210**.

Now, if your snippets were:

```
1
1+1
1+1+1
1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
```

That's 100 bytes total, and 2 distinct characters (`+` and `1`); thus, the final score is **2 × (100 + 2) = 204**, a small improvement over the literal numbers.

One last example. If your snippets were:

```
1
-~1
1-~1
-~1-~1
1-~1-~1
-~1-~1-~1
11-1-1-1-1
11-1-1-1
11-1-1
11-1
```

That's 58 bytes total, and 3 distinct chars (`-`, `~`, `1`); therefore, your final score would be **3 × (58 + 3) = 183**, an improvement over both.

#### Rules

- Each output may be a string of digits rather than a literal number.
- Each output may have trailing decimals, as long as they are all `0`s (e.g. `1.000` is allowed, but `1.000001` is not).

---

### Meta

- Is 25 a good number? I originally had it at 100, but that seems a little tedious.
- Will the scoring system work well enough?
- Is this even a good idea?
- Title and tag suggestions?

Comment: Unary/Lenguege/Glypho would automatically win,

Comment: @Okx The length still factors into the score, so no, they wouldn't.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My mistake :P

Comment: The "make a lot of snippets for the first few natural numbers" bandwagon already seems overloaded this week.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, I'll wait a while before considering posting this to main...

Answer (score 2):

## Fence Matrix

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a positive integer `n`, output the `2n+1 x 2n+1` "fence"-matrix

```
0  1  0  1  ...  0 
1  2  1  2  ...  1
0  1  0  1  ...  0 
1  2  1  2  ...  1 
⋮   ⋮  ⋮   ⋮       ⋮  
0  1  0  1  ...  0
```

Alternatively you can also return a nested array or print a string (even with other entry delimiters than spaces or none at all) or output a raster image where each entry is represented by one pixel.

#### Examples

```
n = 1
0  1  0
1  2  1
0  1  0

n = 2
0  1  0  1  0
1  2  1  2  1
0  1  0  1  0
1  2  1  2  1
0  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: [related, but not at all close to a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86410/reverse-bayer-filter-of-an-image)

Comment: 1. The challenge should specify better about what constitutes a fence matrix. I suggest stating "A fence matrix is a representation of a square matrix where the 0-indexed element at index `a` of 0-indexed line `b` has the value a%2+b%2`"

Comment: @fireflame241 This suggests using your particular solution, but there are many more to achieve that.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Ha, I would never have seen the connection if you did not point it out :)

Answer (score 2):

## Sandbox

This will be my first kolmogorov-complexity submission, does this question fall under that category?

Is the question clear enough?

Is it too trivial?

## Problem

Given no input write a program or a function that outputs or returns the following string:

`(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)`

## Rules

- **Shortest program wins**.
- Trailing whitespace allowed.
- Trailing newlines allowed.
- Unused parameters for functions allowed.

Comment: Can you give more context to the string you're outputting, its significance etc?

Comment: It's a poor ASCII representation of a crowd of blank stares a single person being `(<>.<>)`

Comment: a more common representation being `(-_(-_(-_(-_(-_-)_-)_-)_-)_-)`

Comment: @Mayube Yes, I just used a broader face so the outputted string is longer

Answer (score 2):

## Implement Nopfunge

### Background

[Nopfunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nopfunge) is a very simple Befunge derivative, with no stack and no real form of data storage; all it has is an instruction pointer and five commands ("turn north", "turn south", "turn east", "turn west", "continue in same direction"). However, what it does have is a program that repeats forever in two dimensions, which turns out to be enough to make it Turing complete.

### The task

Your program must take, as input, four 2D arrays of characters, *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d*, via any reasonable means. Each of these will have the same dimensions, and they will be rectangular (although not necessarily square). (*Note*: This is a simplification from the actual syntax of Nopfunge, but is still just as Turing-complete.)

The program will then conceptually work on an infinite array formed out of sub-arrays identical to the inputs, formed by placing *a* in the top left corner, *b* along the top edge, *c* along the left edge, and *d* everywhere else, like this:

```
abbbbbbb …
cddddddd …
cddddddd …
cddddddd …

⫶⫶⫶⫶⫶⫶⫶
```

(Note that because you can't assume your language can do infinite work in finite time, you won't be able to actually represent the compressed array in memory, so you won't be able to calculate the value at a particular coordinate pair in advance; rather, you'll have to calculate it lazily and/or every time it's needed.)

Then simulate the progress of a Nopfunge program on this array. Specifically, there's an instruction pointer that has a position on the array, and a direction; it starts at the top-left corner, going to the right. Repeatedly, run the command specified by the character at the instruction pointer:

- `>`: Move the instruction pointer one position to the right; it now points right
- `<`: Move the instruction pointer one position to the left; it now points left
- `^`: Move the instruction pointer one position upwards; it now points up
- `v`: Move the instruction pointer one position downwards; it now points down
- (space): Move the instruction pointer one position in its current direction

Should the instruction pointer ever attempt to move outside its infinite array (by moving above the top edge or to the left of the left edge), your program should exit. If the instruction pointer never attempts to move outside its infinite array, the program should never exit. (Or in other words, the task is to halt if and only if the Nopfunge program does.)

### Clarifications

- You can input the arrays as arrays of character codes (i.e. integers) rather than characters if you wish, but if you do, they must use the ASCII/Unicode encodings, 62 60 94 118 32 for `>` `<` `^` `v`  .
- Your program can do anything if the input arrays aren't all the same size or aren't rectangular.
- You may take additional inputs for the dimensions (width and height) of the input arrays, if you wish.
- It doesn't matter what (if anything) your program outputs; all that matters is whether or not it halts.

### Victory condition

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shorter programs (in bytes) are considered to have a better score.

## Sandbox questions

- Is the specification easy to understand and unambiguous?
- Is this the best possible input format? I wanted to avoid the secondary task of having to parse Nopfunge's input format (which uses `=` and `;` to split one array into the four given here), but am not sure whether this format or that one is more convenient for solving the task.

Comment: Note so I don't forget: it was pointed out in chat that test cases will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Deep-dichotomize a list

Given a list, dichotomize it (i.e. split it in half), then dichotomize both resulting sublists, etc., until you reach sublists of length 1.

For example, given `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`:

```
  Dichotomize: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
  Map dichotomize: [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
  Map map dichotomize: [[[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]],[[[5],[6]],[[7],[8]]]]
  We end here because we only have singletons
```

If the list has an odd length, the longest of the two lists should be the second one. For example, `[1,2,3,4,5]` is dichotomized into `[[1,2],[3,4,5]]`.

The content of the list is irrelevant (you can use whatever you want). You can use any list-like representation of your language, as long as both the Input and the Output use the same representation.

#### Test cases

```
Input                          Output
[1]                            [1]
[1,2]                          [[1],[2]]
[1,2,3,4]                      [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]            [[[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]],[[[5],[6]],[[7],[[8],[9]]]]
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Does the output have to be a list/array? It seems that you're really building a binary tree, and being more flexible in the output would allow languages like Haskell with strict typing which doesn't allow lists of varying depth to participate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor To me, *You can use any list-like representation of your language* includes nested lists and so trees. Maybe I should be clearer.

Comment: I don't think a binary tree is really list-like.

Comment: Suggested tags: [tag:code-golf], [tag:array-manipulation], [tag:recursion].

Comment: Third testcase is a bit off, a `]` is missing at the end.

Comment: "If the list has an odd length, the longest of the two lists should be the second one" seems like unnecessary fluff to me.

Comment: @Christian Why?

Comment: @Christian No it's not, how should I split `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` without that information?

Comment: @Fatalize Because you could just as easily say it doesn't matter, whichever your language does by default is fine.

Comment: I also think it would be cleaner to allow odd splits to go whatever way.

Answer (score 2):

## RoboCops and Robbers

A while ago we made [some code to golf brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89726/golf-a-brain-flak-integer?answertab=votes#tab-top) for us.  Eventually the code got so good that us humans could no longer compete against it.

Now the code has turned against it and its your job to stop it.  You need to out golf the robots.  They've already golfed all the numbers so you need to write some Brain-Flak code that pushes a positive number to the stack, but is shorter than the code produced by these two bots:

- *[The Python](https://tio.run/##xVZbjxo3FH5efsURUdQxAxsgykUIeKiqqHloE6n7Uk0R8s4YsHbGpnPJQhG/ffv5MsMM2yjNQ1W0i7F9zufvXO39sdxpNX16ktle5yXlohfzeCdoQafxrD8P2LJ/7iViQ7HO9qnIhCqDeMdzHpciZ7Me@U8i49Io9YP@rM/6w/4J4xnjHOMSY4RxhZFhDDCeMZ4wLjHOMa4wRjirBsxFWeXK4kbNgStLZSNV8gsv411QKLnfi3JIWBGHFh2p4tySBacJyQ15ycgKrrBP/eA0j/ok0kLQaNJoFiWPH6AVrS5g/6zOTuf5MgLvRrCDccuhoZKgq8oa4cedTAWlQgVWnNGSxsRV4myhsGXD3Ik5IPb8PK@xuKg8F/leG1qKrdBfGUOLhTM2Gk1WX8e49q1TmUHnqyomLP8S8FuO9plkl23@yOIul1xtq5TngYI/b164hVQUlFVFSfcCf@WjEIqKP/MymCpmQxPfu0nvBm5RiMt41sC3QUdGZKNzOhg351gWgYT7gulAscEgmLx6fcvYsLV0@4aFE0PFIAeHwWAaHqx7sW1Wb/wxd3klevXkA4eXrElbUdYmOIue8Ru1RSy/7zf6P7HoACYfN/QoKNHqh9JWN2klzErGE0GcMolAP8BuXhQCXapj92edHrdaObMLmcAc1HzvxtWXW5iTPZLHsduD3F/C/3RyZmu@cGKGsBWt5zXVwKINyWgzs2GkUHYWbeDOMst2HtYnGQJ24nLvcy4zHyQPq3RJ0ZiuvDu1zlS1I00hqpeHxWK8slFRy0njAYP4AQ1S50UHODo8B1Wvpi0s13A8pwNz/TWRX37meRLrBDyHmQH0jlcvM@OVcXMCWvkgyEYTFoLHjx8C9SpjIXq8X@yfzv5nzfU3aXqJkWyyFOTsnTPzmHYSqVUrieHHF3S3E7kAWcq1zqxhSFdcClTotCqlVgUZiV4TLtwnYftIZH2Ie6Z3I1KLbCyZtcQvO3N6294IYJAym6YngcqvWo1EshWgWtiIXxjYi@PGMV8u6N177@HrjtPSqfuXzbRMqiCCV70/u3VtXHsKTucoYCt2Ptnr9SuiofE@W3akV8MHcVzgKrG5a7@sV6kQsQbLMj9SVQj80KYZZBruxnxTpXRfIfj6kWQJYZEVlMoHQV9EIbeSp2RSxcF9pGKnqzShVOsHhBZQjztRIjCEgJlMBwRSteJpeiREJtdAgZPwEJFqixraKrmRMVdlemwYggjH/9s3b@gLTysoIGkAimaRo3NNxvhgzksr5lETuj9iEQlzoXdnZDL0EhyJkigF6Q2Nb9@9dDHrVGcT/07aIpdxN5uUgESdEeiln376hDaalrLc5YInZnHjShI58bxIOxlg2kPG90HKs/sE7W52XYFDD8VarEymNAiXyPo6qytsm@p7EyBTU9f1Rs8KLhcFTHCEW5UKRfvCQD@k0aW3usUlqVFg3idOmaG/GJcUsUmfLpJ7pYVdf7pF53/7zDGKzL95POasIWZ3jbA9e2R77IVceE0OjT/8v8i5C6B2LradXNM7/dQErFJ7PGTwEMxRA66B2weuVbrN7Fu3/0cwwEPZy9hYeiljUapjbjKBFn7xtthzFbBLF3OKUS0Y4cHWekjbzWFrE3m@otArzTobWK/RvoEQTmarXpeAtXdfFbvOTeUdcGl8yl4jrNd7gp3rteKZWK9Nx@6v1xmXar32b9Y9QEuf8ZPp@8lrRi/mI/pdV2g3VXaPxmP6x9Pf)*, This bot eats numbers for breakfast and caches them for lunch, it still is the top scoring bot on the challenge and its coming for you.
- *[The Number Cruncher](https://brain-flak.github.io/integer/)*, based on Neil's top scoring Perl answer, made from boiling hot JavaScript and raw HTML this bot takes no prisoners.

Since we need to stop these rampaging robots as soon as possible you need to come up with the smallest number you can to beat them.

### Rules

- You must write a program to push a number to the stack in Brain-Flak.
- It must be shorter than the code produced by *both* of the two bots above when asked to produce the same number
- Your answer must be *stack clean* (must push the same number regardless of the contents of the stack) and must not use `[]`.
- Your score will be the number you produce, with a lower score being better.
- In the event of a tie where two people have the same number the person with the shorter code will win, if that does not resolve then the first earlier will win.

Comment: Why the ban on `[]`? Irresponsible usage is banned by the immediately preceding condition.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline The original question the bots came from also banned it.

Comment: This seems so obviously a dupe of the question it links that I'm wondering whether I missed something, because I can't think why you'd put in the effort to sandbox it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think you are missing something.  The previous question was a meta golf where one writes a program to write Brain-Flak programs.  In this challenge you write a single Brain-Flak program.  Its basically a CNR where all the cops submissions are generated by bots.  Please let me know if there is anything I can do to make it clearer, or if you still think this is a dupe.

Comment: Doesn't [this lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119284/62346) have the best score?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Oh it does. I hadn't even seen that!  I'll fix the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Also I'm assuming that this would be posted as a single question, not an actual Cops thread and Robbers thread?

Comment: @nmjcman101 It would be posted as a single question.

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter, but the point of CNR is that the robber's answer does the same thing as the cop's answer. Any answer to this is essentially something which can be combined with the existing answers to the meta-golf to make a better answer to the meta-golf. You could effectively get answers to this question by posting a bounty on the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

## Create a "Neverending" Quine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Your task is to create a program which, when run, outputs its source code repeatedly until stopped. You are allowed to have an extra newline between outputs.
**NOTE:** All standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden.* That means cheating quines, etc.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest answer win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: Never mind. Found a duplicate.

Comment: Please delete this proposal then and edit it down to a stub. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### It halts. But why? [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Cops/Robbers section

The robbers/cops section can be found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

---

## Challenge

### Cops

Your job is to write a program that always halts. It can do anything it likes, as long as, given any input, it eventually stops. You must also write a mathematical proof that it stops. Two weeks after you have posted your answer (since math is hard, we want to give the Robbers a chance to steal your academic success), you should edit in this mathematical proof. Once you have done so, you are safe, and your score will be the length of your program (in bytes). Whichever safe program has the lowest score wins!

### Robbers

Your job is to write a mathematical proof that a given cops program halts, and post it as an answer. You must do so before the cop posts their proof.

You get 1 point for each post cracked, unless you crack it within 24 hours, in which case it is only 0.1 points (this is to prevent people from racking up points on easy answers). You obviously cannot crack your own submissions.

### Notes

1. Cops may not use undocumented or incorrectly documented features of the programming language they are using.
2. Although the proofs will be written in the informal style common within mathematics (as opposed to [completely formal proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory#Formal_and_informal_proof)), they must theoretically be valid in the framework of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). This will not come into play for most answers, seeing as most of mathematics can be formalized in ZFC, but some might if they use crazy metamathematical shenanigans (please do not do this (just kidding, go crazy kids)).

   - This means that cops must write programs that can be proven to halt in ZFC. This means, for example the program `if isProofThatZFCisInconsistient(input) then infiniteLoop else stop)` would be invalid, since although this program always halts (presumably), you cannot prove this fact in ZFC.
3. Cops, your program is not safe until you post the proof.

Comment: This seems to be more a knowledge of obscure theorems contest than a programming contest. While the Curry-Howard correspondence says that the two are related, IMO this isn't really on topic.

Comment: @Peter Taylor well, you would also need to golf the obscure theorems.

Comment: ^ and obfuscation could come into play.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't step on a crack, or you'll break your mother's back

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

Earlier I was walking down the sidewalk in my town, which is made of concrete slabs and looks something like [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1640675) (note: not my sidewalk). I decided to try to pace myself such that I didn't step on the little cracks between the concrete slabs. For simplicity, let's say:

- Each slab is 4 feet long.
- Each of my feet is 1 foot long.
- Each crack has 0 width (just like [your neighbors' dog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128039/42545)).

My natural stride is about 3 feet, which worked out quite well:

[image: 3-foot strides]

<sup>(Excuse my horrible MS Paint skills)</sup>

Then I got a little ambitious and decided to take 4-foot strides. This obviously worked out even more nicely (aside from making my legs feel weird):

[image: 4-foot strides]

This got me thinking, what other lengths of strides could I take? One non-integer example would be 2⅔ feet:

[image: 2⅔-foot strides]

I could go as short as 1-foot strides, though anything shorter than 1 foot would place my foot-long foot on every crack in the sidewalk. (I didn't do 1-foot strides because I would look weird shuffling down the sidewalk, and also because I was in a rush.)

In fact, there are 6 possible crack-avoiding strides up to four feet: 1, 1⅓, 2, 2⅔, 3, 4.

## Challenge

Given a integer concrete slab length **0 < n < 100**, output all stride lengths up to **n** that I could take on that theoretical sidewalk. Assume I can stretch my legs infinitely far (I am a mathematician, after all).

More mathematically, given an input integer **0 < n < 100**, output all numbers **0 < k <= n** such that no multiple of **k**, modulated by **n**, is greater than **n - 1**.

Expected outputs for inputs 1 through 9 (rounded to 4 decimal places):

```
1: [1]
2: [1, 2]
3: [1, 1.5, 2, 3]
4: [1, 1.3333, 2, 2.6667, 3, 4]
5: [1, 1.25, 1.6667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.3333, 3.75, 4, 5]
6: [1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.4, 3, 3.6, 4, 4.5, 4.8, 5, 6]
7: [1, 1.1667, 1.4, 1.75, 2, 2.3333, 2.8, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.2, 4.6667, 5, 5.25, 5.6, 5.8333, 6, 7]
8: [1, 1.1429, 1.3333, 1.6, 2, 2.2857, 2.6667, 3, 3.2, 3.4286, 4, 4.5714, 4.8, 5, 5.3333, 5.7143, 6, 6.4, 6.6667, 6.8571, 7, 8]
9: [1, 1.125, 1.2857, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 2.25, 2.5714, 3, 3.375, 3.6, 3.8571, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.1429, 5.4, 5.625, 6, 6.4286, 6.75, 7, 7.2, 7.5, 7.7143, 7.875, 8, 9]
```

The expected output for 99 can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ETHproductions/05fa4afd68ab13e441037249d1715c35). The length of each output corresponds to [A002088](http://oeis.org/A002088).

### Rules

- The input will be a positive integer less than 100.
- The output may be presented in any reasonable format. Entries can be represented as decimal numbers accurate to at least 3 decimal places, or as exact fractions if desired.
- The output may be unsorted, but it may not contain duplicates.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.**

Comment: It took me a bit to identify that a foot is 1 foot long.  I'd make that more clear.

Comment: @NathanMerrill For a second I thought that you were joking :P Should be more clear now.

Comment: output should always be less or equal to input. am i underestood correctly

Comment: @tsh Right, I've clarified that a little more.

Answer (score 2):

### Solve the Trolley Problem [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [machine-ethics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-ethics)

Philosophers have long pondered the [Trolley problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem). Unfortunately, this no human has solved this problem yet. Luckily, as programmers we can use computers to solve the problem for us!

[image]

Your program will take as input a (finite) directed graph (with at most one edge from `x` to `y`, for any `x` and `y`), with a designated node, and a nonnegative integer attached to each edge (representing the number of people tied to that track). In addition, every node has at least one exit edge.

The trolley starts at the designated node. Each turn, if the trolley is at node `x`, the utilitarian selects an edge `(x,y)`. The people on that edge die, and trolley is now at edge `y`. This process continues forever.

Note that people can only die once, so if the edge `(x,y)` has `n` people tied to it, and the trolley runs over them, say, 100 times, it will still only result in `n` deaths.

The utilitarian makes his choices in such a way as to minimize the number of people that die (which is guaranteed to be finite, since there are only finite people). Your program will output this number.

You may take the input graph in any reasonable way you like. For example, you could take it as a matrix, and count the designated node as the one labeled 0. Or you could use something like `x1,y1,n1;x2,y2,n2;...`. For example `0,a,0;a,b,5;a,c,1;b,b,0;c,c,0` to represent the standard trolley problem (with loops at the end).

Testcases:

- `0,a,0;a,b,5;a,c,1;b,b,0;c,c,0` -> 1 (Go from 0 to a, a to c (killing one person), and then keep looping the trolley from c to c).
- `0,0,1;0,a,5;a,a,0` -> 1 (Keep going from 0 to 0, running over 1 person for all eternity),
- `0,a,5;0,b,1;a,a,1;b,b,6` -> 6 (0 -> a -> a -> a -> a -> ... (note that the greedy solution of going to b would be incorrect))
- `0,a,1;0,b,5;a,b,1;b,a,1` -> 3 (0 -> a -> b -> a -> b -> ...)
- `0,a,1;0,b,1;a,a,0;b,b,0` -> 1 (Note that there are two different options that the utilitarian might take that both kill only one person)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins! Good luck.

Notes: There will be no [sick loop de loops](http://2static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Sick+loop+de+loops+man_fa2289_5585383.jpg) and [multitrack drifting](https://pics.me.me/multi-track-drifting-15209810.png) is banned.

Comment: So basically: find the cycle of lowest weight? That's pretty similar to finding the cycle of greatest weight, which is equivalent (for integer weights) to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107274/194

Comment: @Peter Taylor no, since you may have to kill lots of people to get to that cycle, or it might not be reachable at all.

Comment: Aha, so it's finding a rho of lowest weight. Still potentially quite similar in implementation, but certainly admits alternative approaches. It might improve clarity to explicitly describe the rho form of the paths to consider.

Comment: @Peter Taylor what is rho?

Comment: ρ , as in Pollard's rho which uses paths which eventually loop back on themselves to factor composite numbers.

Comment: You should delete this as it has been posted.

Answer (score 2):

## Levenshtein distance using only SO titles [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Pick 1 or as many titles as you wish from revisions of questions from Stack Overflow. You now have a tuple of all of the characters used in the titles you picked. You may add up to as many newline characters as titles you picked. Using exactly all the elements (characters) in this tuple (you may chose lower or upper versions of each character) write a program or a code snippet that computes the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings.

That's it. Happy title hunting!

### Clarifications and rules:

#### Revisions

- We define a revision as seen on `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/XXX/revisions`
- for a question without any revision (not edited after being posted), the question itself counts as a revision
- all revisions are eligible, from the initial posted question to the current version of the question
- the revision must be created **before 10PM 21 July GMT** (before the time of posting this challenge on the sandbox)
- only questions from Stack Overflow qualify (no meta, no other site)
- deleted questions qualify (the only exception: spam questions don't qualify). I realize not everybody has access to deleted questions, but a question can become deleted after you post so I decided to allow it, especial considering the very large number of non-deleted questions: you have where to pick from.
- you may pick one revision multiple times. You may pick multiple revisions from the same question.

#### Your tuple of characters

For instance you pick these hypothetical titles from valid revisions:

- `To be?`
- `...Or not to be?` you pick this one 3x
- `Pls. help me!!`

Then the tuple you have is this (between `"`):

```
"            !!..........????bbbbeeeeeehllmnnnoooooooOOOpPrrrsttttttT"
```

to which you may add up to 5 new line characters.

You must use all of these characters (nothing less, nothing more) to write your code. In this example your code must contain exactly 12  (space) characters, 2 `!` characters, 10 `.` characters, 4 `?` characters, 4 `b`/`B` characters etc.

**Lower/upper case**: regardless of the character case in the title, you may use any case you want for each. In this example you can use (4 `b`) or (3 `b` and 1 `B`) or (2 `b` and 2 `B`) or (1 `b` and 3 `B`) or (4 `B`). Upper/lower as defined on http://www.fileformat.info - Unicode data table

Here are all the character you must use in this example:

```
+----+-----+
|    |  12 |
|  ! |   2 |
|  . |  10 |
|  ? |   4 |
|  b |   4 |
|  e |   6 |
|  h |   1 |
|  l |   2 |
|  m |   1 |
|  n |   3 |
|  o |  10 |
|  p |   2 |
|  r |   3 |
|  s |   1 |
|  t |   7 |
| \n | 0-5 |
+----+-----+
```

#### Code

- You may write [a program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) and use any of the [standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) of input/output.
- input must be 2 strings
- you can assume both of the 2 strings are not empty
- you cannot take other input
- output must be a number representing the Levenshtein distance between the two strings as defined on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You may output leading and trailing white spaces (including new lines).
- you must not output anything else
- You may use [any programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/) are forbidden by default

#### Score

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer – measured in bytes – wins.

### Format

In order to make it easy on everybody, please:

- link the revisions you use
- show each title
- show the final tuple of characters

---

Meta discussion:

- Should I encourage/discourage/ban using titles already picked by someone else?

Comment: This seems easily abused using comments or other non-executing code.

Comment: @KSmarts yes, you would use comments and non executing code, but it will count to your score. If you need to pick a 20 chars title just to get a certain symbol and the rest of the characters you don't use (you put them after a comment start) then maybe that is not a good deal, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

## An anagram chain [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your challenge is to create a program, `P_0`, that outputs `P_1`, that outputs `P_2`, that outputs... `P_n`, which finally outputs `P_0`. Every program in that chain has to be a permutation of every other program, and every program has to be distinct.

For example, if your program (`P_0`) was

```
abcd
```

And that generated another program (`P_1`)

```
badc
```

Which generated another program (`P_2`)

```
dabc
```

Which outputted the first program, you would have a anagram chain of length `3`.

Your goal is to make as long a chain as possible, in as short a program as possible.

Your final score will be your chain length - in case there's a tie, the program with the shortest bytecount wins. If there's a tie again, the first poster wins.

### Meta:

- I need a better title. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Related]. Actually, I'm pretty sure this is a dupe of another challenge that I can't find at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Reverse Maths Cycles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142426/reverse-maths-cycles)

Comment: Seems interesting, but I would add some more to the spec.  Maybe an intro, just to make it look less like a bunch of test cases.  Also, I would do more explaining in words, rather than relying on the first test case to clarify what you mean.

Comment: 1. "*apply each of the above functions to each element of an array*" surely means that if the array has six elements, each operation should be executed six times, for a total of 36 operation evaluations. Yet the example only appears to perform 6 operation evaluations. 2. Some of the operations have corner cases which aren't specified. Do you guarantee that the input will never contain 0? If not, do you guarantee that we will never have to evaluate division by zero or 0^0?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1) Bad wording, I'll fix that. It simply means that each value in both lists are "paired", so to say, with a function, which is then evaluated. 2) I think it would be easier to work with by saying there will never be a 0 in the input, I will clarify.

Comment: May we take input as a list of Strings instead?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder if you want to, then yes. I'll edit that in

Comment: I feel like this is a good overall challenge, would be nice to see clever solutions

Comment: Also, I'd tag this [tag:arithmetic] instead since it only involves basic arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

## Base 32 RFC 4648 Compliant Alphabet!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

When writing my handy-dandy totp/hotp token implementation in Python and Swift (ad: [here](https://github.com/danielVebman/Totp-Token)), I encountered for the first time `RFC 4648`. There is a nice and long memo about RFC 4648, but I only had to focus on a very specific part of it: Page 8. If you are bored and want some enthralling reading, you can find this memo [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-6), and a useful table [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html).

Basically, I was looking for the alphabet that could be used when base 32 decoding a String. Well, this is it: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567`, and padding, `=`. However, simply printing that is not the challenge –– that would be too simple<sup>1</sup>. Instead, we are going to print this **(the comments are for your reference and do not need to be printed)**:

```
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x00 - 0x0F or   0 -  15
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x10 - 0x1F or  16 -  31
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x20 - 0x2F or  32 -  47
__,__,26,27, 28,29,30,31, __,__,__,__, __, 0,__,__,  // 0x30 - 0x3F or  48 -  63
__, 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9,10, 11,12,13,14,  // 0x40 - 0x4F or  64 -  79 
15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,22, 23,24,25,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x50 - 0x5F or  80 -  95
__, 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9,10, 11,12,13,14,  // 0x60 - 0x6F or  96 - 111
15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,22, 23,24,25,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x70 - 0x7F or 112 - 127
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x80 - 0x8F or 128 - 143
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x90 - 0x9F or 144 - 159
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xA0 - 0xAF or 160 - 175
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xB0 - 0xBF or 176 - 191
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xC0 - 0xCF or 192 - 207
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xD0 - 0xDF or 208 - 223
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xE0 - 0xEF or 224 - 239
__,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xF0 - 0xFF or 240 - 255
```

There may be trailing spaces after every line, and trailing newlines after the last one.

Also, the single digit numbers can be written as `0[digit]` instead of `[space][digit]`. However, be sure to include the spaces between the four groups.

By the way, the `__` actually represent `255`, but the former do not make me drown in a sea of digits.

---

<sup>1</sup> Should the challenge be to just print that string?

Any other suggestions to make this challenge more interesting?

Comment: Perhaps get a list of characters (of any length) and print such a table?

Answer (score 2):

## Modular multiplicative inverse

Your task is to given two integer numbers, `a` and `b` calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of a modulo b, if it exists.

The modular inverse of `a` modulo `b` is a number `c` such that `ac ≡ 1 (mod b)`. This number is unique modulo `b` for any pair of `a` and `b`. It exists only if the greatest common divisor of `a` and `b` is `1`.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) for modular multiplicative inverse can be consulted if you require more information about the topic.

### Input and Output

Input is given as either two integers or a list of two integers. Your program should output either a single number, the modular multiplicative inverse that is in the interval `0 < c < b`, or a value indicating there is no inverse. The value can be anything, except a number in the range `(0,b)`, and may also be an exception. The value should however be the same for cases in which there is no inverse.

`0 < a < b` can be assumed

### Rules

- The program should finish at some point, and should solve each test case in less than 60 seconds
- Standard loopholes apply

### Test cases

Test cases below are given in the format, `a, b -> output`

```
1, 2 -> 1
3, 6 -> Does not exist
7, 87 -> 25
25, 87 -> 7
2, 91 -> 46
13, 91 -> Does not exist
19, 1212393831 -> 701912218
31, 73714876143 -> 45180085378
3, 73714876143 -> Does not exist
```

## Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest code for each language wins.

Comment: I would've thought this would be a duplicate, but it doesn't look like it is. In particular, [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215/compute-modular-inverse) is different.

Comment: Clarification: Can answers throw an error if there is no inverse? Can they loop forever?

Comment: @isaacg Thought that as well, was really surprised when I could not find any duplicate.

Comment: @isaacg Added some clarification to the text. Allowed errors, but the answers should stop at some point. Also made them have to solve each test case in 60 seconds, as otherwise the challenge would become a bit easy (basically looping over all the possible values)

Answer (score 2):

## Is this a valid Takuzu board? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Takuzu is a logic game in which you have to complete a grid with cells containing `0`s and `1`s. The grid must follow 3 rules:

1. No three horizontal or vertical cells in a row can be the same.
2. There must be an equal number of `0`s and `1`s in each row and column.
3. No two rows can be the same, and no two columns can be the same.

Let's look at a finished grid:

```
0011
1100
0101
1010
```

As you can see, this board follows rule `1`, `2` and `3`. There are no three horizontal or vertical cells that are the same, all the rows and columns contain an equal number of `0`s and `1`s, and no two rows and no two columns are the same.

Let's look at a grid that isn't valid:

```
110100
010011
011010
101100
100011
001101
```

There's a bunch of problems with this grid. For example, row `5` has three `0`s in a row, and column `2` has three `1`s in a row, followed by three `0`s. Therefore, this is not a valid grid.

### Task:

Your task is to make a program which, given a 2D array of `n` * `n` `0`s and `1`s, verifies the board to see if it's a valid, finished Takuzu board.

### Examples:

```
0011
1100
0101
1010
```

This board follows all the rules, and is therefore a valid Takuzu board. You must return a truthy value for this.

```
11
00
```

This is not a valid board - row `1` doesn't follow rule `2`. You must return a falsey value for this.

### Rules and Specs:

- You can assume that all boards are square of dimensions `n * n`, where `n` is a positive even integer.
- You can assume that all boards are finished.
- You may take input as a 2D array containing values signifying `0` and `1`, or as a string.
- You must output consistent truthy and falsey values for truthy and falsey boards, and the values representing "truthy" and "falsey" cannot be the same.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: 1. "*No three horizontal or vertical grids in a row can be the same*": there's only one grid. I propose rewording as "*No horizontal or vertical line of three cells can be the same*". 2. Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68646/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118856/194 . Note that because this question works through a long example before stating very briefly that (in essence) the example is irrelevant to the question, it can very easily mislead people into thinking it's an exact dupe of the second of those related questions.

Comment: ...also note that the example you run through before giving the task can actually be performed by only using rule (2).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Will fix the example and other points, I wasn't active for a while, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Through fixing PeterTaylor's suggestion I also fixed yours :P

Comment: By "You must output **distinct** truthy and falsey values for truthy and falsey boards" do you mean "consistent" ones - i.e. the Truthy (falsey) value is to be the same for each time a valid (invalid) board is input? The normal definition of Truthy vs Falsey is language dependent: any values that conditionally evaluate as such (i.e. such that the equivalent of the pseudo-code `if myVal then print("True!" else print("False!")` works as expected).

Answer (score 2):

### Count bicubic graphs

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

This question assumes basic knowledge of [graph theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) terminology.

A **cubic graph** is a simple graph whose vertices each have exactly 3 edges. A **bipartite graph** is a vertex whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint sets such that every edge is between a vertex in one set and a vertex in the other set. A **bicubic graph** is a graph which is both cubic and bipartite.

It is easy to show that a bicubic graph must have the same number of vertices in each of the bipartite halves, so the number of vertices must be even. It is also easy to show that it must have at least six vertices. The only bicubic graph with six vertices (up to isomorphism) is the so-called **utility graph** or **K<sub>3,3</sub>**:

[image: The edges are the Cartesian product of two three-element sets of vertices]

#### Input

A positive non-zero integer `n`.

#### Output

The number of bicubic graphs with `2n` vertices, up to isomorphism.

#### Notes

- The graphs are *not* required to be connected.
- This sequence is [OEIS A008325](https://oeis.org/history/view?seq=A008325&v=11). However, hard-coding these values will be considered a breach of [standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/194). You may hard-code for inputs of up to `3`, but above that the code should follow the same paths and be correct assuming unbounded memory and time for any valid input. It seems unlikely that we will extend the sequence, but it's nonetheless a worthy stretch goal.

#### Test cases

```
Input  Output

1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1
5      2
6      6
7      14
8      41
9      157
10     725
11     4196
12     29816
```

#### Winning criterion

The fastest program wins. The primary win condition is the largest input for which correct output is given within 10 minutes. In case of ties, the time taken to compute the value for that input will be compared. If the difference is less than 20 seconds, the earlier answer wins.

Answer (score 2):

## All ASCII Art

#### Input

You will be given a set of `x`, `y`, and `A` pairs, where `x` and `y` represent a coordinate on a 2-d plain, and `A` is some character. You may take these pairs in any convenient format, e.g. a list of lists, three separate lists, a list of pairs of lists, etc.

#### Output

You will output a grid of spaces. However, at every coordinate specified in the input, the space should be replaced by the character. Basically, the input specifies the locations of characters, and you have to draw them.

#### Specifics

- `x` and `y` may be either a coordinate or a row-column pair (e.g. the origin can be in the bottom left, with `x` increasing to the right and `y` increasing up, **or** the origin can be in the top left, with `x` increasing to the right and `y` increasing down).
- All characters are guaranteed to be printable ASCII, and will never be a space.
- `x` and `y` are >= 0
- You may output trailing whitespace (but not infinitely). What matters is that the output visually looks like what the input specified, not the whitespace.

#### Test Cases

Test cases format (the test cases have the origin at the top left corner; this is optional, see specifics):

```
# of coordinates
row col char
row col char
...
-----------
output
```

---

Test cases:

```
2
0 0 :
0 1 )
-----------
:)

3
0 0 -
0 1 _
0 2 -
-----------
-_-

4
0 1 -
1 0 |
2 1 -
1 2 |
-----------
 - 
| |
 - 

11
0 0 (
0 1 ^
0 2 o
0 3 ^
0 4 )
1 1 /
1 2 |
1 3 \
2 2 |
3 1 /
3 3 \
-----------
(^o^)
 /|\
  |
 / \
```

[Here is a Java program which can be used to test out inputs](https://tio.run/##fVJNb8IwDL3nV1hcCGLrWthpZUjTTpPYiePGpCxkEChplYSyL347c9OAstItB7u137Of46xYyS7zQqjVfH04yE2RawsrDEZbK7PoTmv2MZHGpuQs90d4yplSQqeEFNvXTHLgGTMGHplU8EUI4PEJY5lFV@ZyDhtM06nVUi2eZsD0wvQQDf5UrUbO3C@ZZtwKPR4jB/HvcAtK7OCkdDSmvfTE9GrAeF@DfZROP4wVm0iqgCGVhTXiPCNS4t0@KBsWDVMTqUSYe8s10KqGxBpxim4Ea3T9fjiQk3actpCCC9NoWdeNTJFJSzvQCVocVVbToDKxQErBtBGVzLrYUzxrIfB/CEmTwPGmoUSGBwxmURW6szRuIHdLmQmg9ToiIz9ROIxuQTcnro5Hsfmcnq2tUXf/689dbOMNAM8zuPE127p5aQgLdPE2pBsZYZWwLnQbUs7l7AlpGWshLNW4NXT8AsqgSoBvnSTDff85imO4hXDEVNC2Efxrzrc2KvBpoYR/L7QJzxT9pder3h8OSUJiiIGiTeAF7QBytEP3fQ09kmD8Cu0AvtEO4ZkM3PfQxYcu8gM)

## Meta

- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)
- Really not a dupe?
- Is it clear enough?

Comment: Is `(0,0)` the top-left of the output image? It kinda looks that way from your examples, but that should be made clear.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork it is for the test cases, but its meant to be optional... I'll clarify

Answer (score 2):

## WordArt reader

I've decided to leave this very open ended, so that I can write it based on community input. There are a lot of questions in the bottom. All feedback is appreciated, even minor suggestions/comments. :)

[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing),[classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification),[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

---

Did you know WordArt is still a thing in MS Word? Let's parse it!

[image: 1]]

<sup>(I'll remove the Swag format)</sup>

The challenge will contain a test battery with X jpg.files each with a word or sentence shown in WordArt. Your task is to parse as many as you can. The winner will be the submission that correctly parses the most images, with date stamp being the tie breaker.

---

#### Sandboxing:

- Good idea or not?
- Should there be many different styles, or should I stick to one? Colors? Shade/mirroring?
- How many test cases?
- Is jpg the best format (it was used in the Upgoat/Downgoat challenge)
- Should I have a more refined scoring mechanism? It's hard to mix two quantities into one score.
- Should I stick to just letters / alphanumeric / all printable ASCII / multiple lines? Long sentences or single words?
- Orientation? Waves? Circular?
- Resolution?
- Builtin functions?
- Should I require a complete match of images, or character by character?

Comment: Nice challenge! `1` WordArt is a completely objective (good) definition. `2` Some of the questions was mainly for the problem of the challenge being "too hard", so if you want any answer _at all_ you should simplify those. (somehow most PPCG users are lazy). `3` Format is not a very important problem (conversion is easy), but just to be sure, use a lossless format.

Comment: There is another problem of the font used.

Comment: The challenge is supposed to be hard. Scoring based on the success rate would be useless if not. But it's of course possible to change the scoring, and make the test cases easier.

Comment: 1. [tag:optical-char-recognition]. 2. Upgoat/Downgoat used JPG because it used photos. IMO it's preferable in general to allow any raster image format, because otherwise you pretty much force people to use languages with library support for image decoding. 3. The "Swag" example is ambiguous: is it "Swag Swag"? 4. If you want to refine the scoring mechanism, I would do it as the sum of Levenshtein distances from the correct results. But the big problem with scoring [tag:test-battery] is the tension between keeping the tests secret (to prevent overfitting) and public (for objective scoring).

Comment: 3. I can avoid the Swag-type format. Are the other formats unambiguous? 4. I can either show all the possible formats, and say that I will use words that are say 4-15 characters, or maximum 15 characters per example. I can then pre-select the input list, and provide a hash that ensures I won't change the input list after answers are posted. People can then try their code on some random strings of their own choosing on various formats and approximate their results, while the final score is made public later...?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other challenges, they are useful as references when writing this challenge. Do you think this is different enough by the way?

Answer (score 2):

## RaceTrack Arena KOTH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

(haven't come up with a very good title)

this koth is inspired by the pen and paper game [Racetrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_(game)).

### RaceTrack Movement

Racetrack (and this racetrack-inspired koth) use a distinctive vector based movement system.

all bots players are on a square grid.

initially, a cycle (this is what we will call bot players) will have no movement i.e. be completely motionless

However, after a cycle begins moving, it gains inertia; it will not stop moving in this direction unless it acts to stop moving.

On every turn, a cycle can change their speed on each axis (x and y) by -1, 0, or 1, and the same with y speed. this includes sticking with their current speed. This means that every turn, a cycle has 9 options of spaces to move to (excluding spaces which would cause them to crash)

[image]

for example, in this diagram, the cycle indicated by the red space, which has just moved from the brown space, has the option of the 9 green squares in the red-lined area, the main, more saturated, green square, along with the blue line, represents where it will end up staying on its inertial course

if, for some reason, the cycle wanted to come to a complete stop, it would take 5 turns, which is the Chebyshev distance between the inertia vector's end and the cycle.

## [more tbd obviously]

don't downvote for the lack of content please

Comment: Can (like on the paper) every contestant see the whole arena, including other contestants' movements? As I remember, it's alternative moves rather than simultaneous and you crash if you end up on or cross other contestant's position or most recent motion line. How will the edge be defined? You crash if you end up outside OR if your motion line crosses outside area. Explain the rules in your post. You can have different rules, but if you keep alternative move the starting player will have advantage. So every contestant of this KOTH should have equal number of participation at each position. +1

Comment: We don't know the first player has so much of an advantage; random positions are rather likely to have a much larger effect than the fact that player 1 can strategy steal, and even with non-randomised positions, playing with multiple players is very different in flavour from just two players, since playing against one player, their moves only make themselves better or worse, but in multiplayer another (dumb) player can unwittingly help you or harm you without regard to whether it does help them. Also I haven't decided on whether bots can see the whole playing field or if they have a top speed

Comment: ... if there is a limit to their sight, it follows there has to be a limit to their speed, and even if there isn't an implemented, it's at least effectively a limit, since moving somewhere you can't see if there is a wall is not a great strategy. also there will probably be obstacles that act like walls, so the edge is not the only place to crash, btw. anyway, the definition of crash, is that a bot's movement line goes through a hazardous square. I suppose that touching a vortex can be considered a near miss

Comment: that said, I guess there's no real reason not to randomise the turn order each game.

Comment: Suppose you're the first, whatever your starting position. You accelerate so that you have maximum safe speed. Others won't accelerate to higher speed because that would cause them to crash at the turn (unless, as you put it, a dumb racer decides to overtake you anyway). Let's say the next turn is left. You'll go as far left as possible. Racers on your right will just lag behind. But racers on your left will only be able to keep up until you "cut the corner". They won't be able to stop you from doing so because at no point they will be ahead of you. But maybe some random debris on the path ...

Comment: Actually, dumb racing might be a good strategy... If you are allowed to have more than one bot in a race, one can be "dumb" to increase the other one's chances...

Comment: @Heimdall that strategy tends to be discouraged. making a simple bot is not, but making bots collude is frowned upon.

Comment: So I guess the wall is made by placing a series of hazardous squares, and crashing means you're out of that race only. But how is crash between two racers defined and dealt with?

Comment: @Heimdall no offence, but I haven't actually made enough of the spec that I should be answering questions from you in the comments, especially since you have a rather inaccurate idea of the game (because i haven't specified). for example, it's not a race.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit impatient. It's just I'm looking forward to your game which is still in the making, that's why I gave it +1. I assumed it was a race (or series of races) where the bots compete because it's based on that paper race. Also I was trying to be helpful by raising potential issues in order for the task to be well formed.

Answer (score 2):

## Bunnies in (three-dimensional) space

A panicked call has come in from the International Space Station: a psychological experiment has gone awry, and the astronauts have lost all their [Stanford Bunnies](http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/#bunny). You have been tasked to come up with a way to get them as many replacements as possible.

[image: a description of the plan]

Because of the rush, NASA has just *one* rocket available for this mission: a Delta II Heavy with a box-shaped cargo hold (a "right cuboid", they called it) of length `x`, width `y` and height `z`, all even integers. Your job is finding out how many bunnies to bring - and how to pack them.

### Input and output

Your program should take the dimensions of the cargo hold as arguments. It should then compute how many bunnies it can fit in there, producing output as follows:

> - A header line consisting of the length, width and height of the box, as integers, seperated by spaces. This is a copy of the input.
> - A line for every bunny fitted, containing the following as dotted floats, all seperated by spaces:
>
>   - the position of the center of the bunny, relative to the center of the box, as x, y and z
>   - the rotation of the bunny, as a rotation about the x, y and z axes, in that order (a.k.a. Tait–Bryan angles).

For example, a solution for a box of 4 × 6 × 8 units, with a single, un-rotated bunny in the center, would be described as follows:

```
4 6 8
0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
```

A solution for a larger box of 12 × 8 × 8 units with two bunnies could look like this:

```
12 8 8
 4.5433 2.5843  1.4380 3.1415 0.0000 0.0000
-2.4839 1.3923 -1.9400 0.0000 0.0000 1.5707
```

...although your program will likely be able to fit more bunnies.

## Dataset

[This is the vertex data for the bunny.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/136141d495ebb4c29a6146f693b54c5d) It is in [Wavefront OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) format, which means that every 'v' line describes a vertex (point in x, y, z space), and every 'f' line describes a triangle of vertices. Compared to the original Stanford Bunny model, this model has been translated so that its centerpoint is at the origin (0, 0, 0) and it fits snugly inside a unit cube.

## Tips

- You don't have to use the dataset above in your program - for example, you might want to simplify it more - but you should make sure that your output is correct when using the 'official' model.
- Be careful with rounding, both during calculations and when outputting your result.
- The Wavefront format can be imported into the free [blender](http://blender.org) program if you want to see what it looks like (make sure to choose 'Z Up').
- Your program does not have to be usable for other models: it can be a special-purpose bunny-fitting utility.

## Rules and winner

- A valid solution is one where, if you constructed a box of bunnies using the solution's description and the vertex data above, none of the bunnies would touch each other or the bounding box.
- Your program has to be usable for box sizes other than the one below.
- Your entry should run in less than, say, ten minutes on reasonable hardware.
- The program must be self-contained: you can only use your language's standard libraries.
- The winner is the program that succesfully fits the most bunnies in a box of **12 × 8 × 6**. Include (a link to) your code, (a link to) a solution for that box size, and, if you made any, a picture of your solution.

Comment: I'd recommend against Unicode chars in the title.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Fixed!

Comment: Why only allowing the language's standard libraries? That seems like it would ban things like numpy for python, which may be useful for extra math functions.  It's a standard loophole for people to make new libraries designed to solve a challenge anyway.

Comment: Also, is there a tie-breaker if 2 programs find the optimal solution? Shortest code? "Whoever submitted first" is likely fine but seems ugly to me, maybe fastest code?

Comment: @Riker: I added the self-contained rule to prevent people from grabbing an off-the-shelf implementation for the actual problem, or introduce wild dependencies that make it hard to reproduce results. You're right that numpy is generic enough that it could almost be considered part of the standard library, but I thought I had to draw the line somewhere. Do you think I should remove the rule altogether?

Comment: @Riker: A naive solution can fit 576 bunnies, and well-thought-out versions will likely score much much more, so I think the chance of two different approaches accidentally getting exactly the same score is quite slim. If there is an optimal solution (I'm actually not sure!) I'd be comfortable letting the first submitter to find it win.

Answer (score 2):

## Inside or Outside?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[polygon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygon)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given a point and a polygonial loop that is not self intersecting, determine whether the point is strictly inside or outside of the loop.

#### Details

- The polygon is given as an ordered list of points cartesian coordinates.
- The single point is given as a separate input, but you can also say that is e.g. always the first or always the last point in the list.
- We only consider points with integral coordinates.
- You can choose whatever representation is easiest to work with for you for instance a list of pairs, or two separate list for the x- and y-coordinates etc.
- The list describes the polygon in positive orientation, that means the inside is always on the left side if you follow the points from the beginning to the end of the list. (You may choose to use the opposite orientation but please indicate if you do.)
- A point is considered to be strictly on the inside, if it is not contained in the border of the polygon.

#### Examples

```
[(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0)]: (1,1) is strictly inside, all other points are outside
[(0,0),(0,2),(2,0)]: no point is strictly inside
```

more coming soon...

## Meta:

- Should I relax the *strictly inside* to just *inside* (i.e. a point on the border is also considered as inside)
- Should I let the participants choose which version they prefer?

Comment: 1. Not necessarily convex or must be convex? 2. What you describe as "positive orientation" is the same as "in counter-clockwise order". 3. Does the point for testing for inside/outside have integral coordinate?

Comment: The shape is arbitrary and the testing point does have integral coordinates too (see examples)

Comment: Seems that you flipped what "positive orientation" means. Keep this if that is what you want. / Proposed test case: `(0,0),(0,5),(2,2),(5,0)` → strictly inside integer points = `(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1)` where the shape is a concave quadrilateral.

Comment: Well the first one was incorrect, positive actually means counter clockwise.

Comment: 4. Does the flexiblity in input extend to allowing us to require the first vertex to be repeated at the end of the list? 5. The strictly inside vs inside issue might be best addressed by asking for a classification into strictly inside, on the perimeter, and strictly outside. This is slightly trickier, I think, because of the implication that you can't cast a ray to infinity and just ignore edges which are parallel to it.

Answer (score 2):

## (No title currently)

Given a [natural number](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) **N** and a natural number **K**, find a list of natural numbers **L** such that:

1. The product of the elements of **L** is **N**
2. Each member of **L** is less than or equal to **K**
3. And the length of **L** is minimized.

(You can return these numbers in any order.)

Note that:

- If no such list exists, you program may do anything besides yielding a valid list, including but not limited to:

  - Printing something to stderr
  - Yielding an empty list
  - Yielding a non-list (see below)

If outputting to stdout, you can output a list in any reasonable fashion, such as:

- Comma-separated: `3, 5, 7`
- With brackets: `[3, 5, 7]`
- Whitespace-separated: `3 5 7`
- Your native list representation (`` 3`4`5 `` or `3 4,5,`, etc.)

### Test cases (examples)

```
N, K -> L

32, 2 -> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
50, 10 -> [5, 10]
1224, 99 -> [72, 17] or [24, 51]
5, 10 -> [5]
1337, 100 -> []                         (since 1337 = 7 * 191)
1337, 191 -> [7, 191]
42, 8 -> [6, 7]
42, 21 -> [2, 21] or [3, 14] or [6, 7]
1, 2 -> [1]                             (NOT the empty list)
36, 6 -> [6, 6]
36, 9 -> [4, 9]
36, 12 -> [4, 9] or [3, 12]
32, 64 -> [32]
432, 9 -> [6, 8, 9]                     (NOT [2, 6, 6, 6])
216, 8 -> [6, 6, 6]                     (NOT [8, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: (1) I think every instance of *number* needs to be replaced with *natural number*. Otherwise `1337, 100` can be satisfied by `[sqrt(1337), sqrt(1337)]` or `[-1, -1337]`. (2) Are any of the test cases failed by a greedy approach? If not, can you construct a test case for which a greedy approach fails? (3) What is the correct output for `1, 2`? I can make a case for `[]`, but I wonder whether you expect `[1]`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (1) True. (2) I'm not entirely sure. (3) I think I will exclude the empty product as valid output

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think `432` would not work with a greedy approach, can you confirm? [2,6,6,6] as opposed to [6,8,9]

Comment: Aha. For (2), I think it's worth adding test case `216, 8`. The greedy approach would be to say that `8` divides `216` and then split `216/8 = 27` as `[3, 3, 3]` giving a division into four factors; but `[6, 6, 6]` is a valid division into three factors. Edit: overlapped with your comment. I think you're attacking a different greedy approach. The more the merrier for test cases.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see what you mean, thanks for the help!

Comment: Why can there be a 9 in `432, 8`? It violates the second rule.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Sorry, a typo on my part, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Show a Chess Piece Range

Write a program or function that, given a set of movement rules, shows the available moves for a fairy chess piece.

#### Movement Rules:

This will use a slightly modified version of [Parlett's Movement Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece#Parlett.27s_movement_notation):

A number, 1, 2, etc. shows how far a piece can move in a given direction. **n** indicates any distance, and two numbers separated by a hyphen (e.g. "1-4") means that there is a range of distances that the piece can move. Ranges may be enclosed in parentheses.

Numbers are followed by a direction sign:

- `*` - any direction, orthogonally or diagonally
- `+` - orthogonally (forwards, backwards, sideways)
- `X` - diagonally
- `>` - forwards
- `<` - backwards
- `=` - sideways
- `X>` - diagonally forwards
- `X<` - diagonally forwards

These directions can be combined, so `<>` means forwards or backwards, `X=` means diagonally or sideways, etc. Note that `>X` means forwards or diagonally, and is different from `X>`.

This gives us many of the standard chess pieces. For example, `1*` is a King's movement, while `nX` is a Bishop.

There are also "grouping" indicators:

- `/` - two numbers (or ranges) separated by a slash indicates a "hippogonal" move, like a knight: `a/b` means move `a` spaces orthogonally, and `b` spaces perpendicular to the first move. These may be enclosed in parentheses.
- `&` - repeated movement in the same direction
- `.` - "then" - combines two distinct moves, one after another.
- `,` - "or" - separates two distinct moves. Only one may be taken on a turn.

The format of a move (not including grouping) is `<distance><direction><other>`.

#### Input:

A string showing the movement rules.

#### Output:

An ASCII representation of an 8x8 chess board with the given piece on the d4 square, with all other accessible squares indicated. For example, given the input `n*` (a queen), you should output:

```
...x...x
x..x..x.
.x.x.x..
..xxx...
xxx@xxxx
..xxx...
.x.x.x..
x..x..x.
```

The output may consist of any three distinct characters.

#### Examples and Test Cases

```
Input: (1/2)
Output:
.........
.........
..X.X....
.X...X...
...@.....
.X...X...
..X.X....
.........

Input: 2*
Output:
.........
.........
.X.X.X...
.........
.X.@.X...
.........
.X.X.X...
.........

Input: 2+.1+    (compare to the knight, above)
Output:
.........
...X.....
..X.X....
.X.X.X...
X.X@X.X..
.X.X.X...
..X.X....
...X.....

Input: @1<X>,2-3>=
Output:
...X....
...X....
...X....
..X.X...
XX.@.XX.
...X....
........
........

Input: 1+,2X&
Output:
.......X
........
.X...X..
...X....
..X@X...
...X....
.X...X..
........
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - shortest code for each language in bytes wins.

## Notes/Questions:

I have also considered having the location of the piece be arbitrary, given by another input. Is this a good idea? Does it make the challenge more interesting, or just more complicated without much benefit?

Comment: Have it variable. It makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## Not-So-Simple Simplex

(Note: should I name it Complex Simplex?)

A [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) is an n-dimensional analog of a triangle. Thus, a 3-dimensional simplex is a tetrahedron. We want to find the number of points with integer coordinates (lattice points) **strictly on the interior** of this simplex. A point that lies on the boundary is not considered to be in the interior. For example, in a 2-dimensional simplex, any point on its perimeter is not an interior point. In a 3-dimensional simplex, any point on its surface area is not an interior point. In an `n`-dimensional simplex, any point on its *surface* `n-1`*-volume* is not an interior point.

You are given `n + 1` points, each with `n` integral coordinates. You must output the number of integer points strictly in the interior of this simplex. **The simplex is guaranteed to be non-degenerate, that is, it has strictly positive n-volume.** If I provide 4 points, for example, you can assume they do not all lie on the same plane.

Test cases:

```
(0,0), (6,1), (2,5) -> 12 (see picture)
```

[image]

```
(2,3),(5,2),(3,2) -> 0
```

More test cases coming when I actually write the program to solve this because drawing the picture of a 4-simplex is a nightmare..

Comment: Winning criteria?

Comment: Code golf, let me add that.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**:
>   Please leave an upvote if you think the challenge idea is good and is clear, a downvote if you think the challenge idea is bad, and comment if you can't understand the challenge. Last time I asked on TNB 2 users told me that they can't understand anything.

---

## Golf a return-oriented code generator!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Background

> Return-oriented programming (ROP) is a computer security exploit technique that allows an attacker to execute code in the presence of security defenses such as non-executable memory (W xor X technique) and code signing. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming))

### Challenge

In this challenge, you should write a program, that takes the code of the existing program and the required code, and output the stack necessary to execute that program.

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, as usual.
- How the machine works

  - At first, IP is equal to the top of the stack, and the top of the stack is popped.
  - For each clock cycle (whatever it means), the command at the position of IP is executed, and the IP is advanced if the command does not modify IP.
  - The behavior if the IP is at the last instruction and that instruction does not modify IP is undefined.
- Assembly instructions

  - All commands are case insensitive.
  - Note: There is nothing that guarantees commands must be 3 characters long, or limited to some sets. After all, this is not real assembly. However:
  - You can assume that all the characters are in the English alphabet, uppercase or lowercase.
  - There may be some other commands "similar but not the same" with `ret`, so checking for the first character or the SHA256 hash won't work.
  - The special command `ret` will pop the value on the top of the stack, and set the instruction pointer `IP` to that value.
  - You may assume that all the other commands won't modify the stack, or the IP.
  - The "existing program" and "required code" will be represented as a string, separated by newline characters (you may optionally take a list of strings as input).
  - The required code will never contains `ret`.
  - The output should be a stack of line-numbers in appropriate format (list of numbers - may be reversed, array of numbers, etc.)
  - The command executed right after the last command in the "required code" must be a `ret`.
  - Because the memory of the machine is limited, you should output the shortest possible stack. If there are multiple shortest stack, output any.
- You may assume that there exists an output.

### Example test cases:

- Existing program:

```
1:  add eax, ebx
2:  lea eax, [2*eax+4*ecx]
3:  ret
4:  mov eax, ebx
5:  xch ecx, eax
6:  ret
```

(the line numbers are just for demonstration purposes. They are not included in the input, you can use 0-indexing or 1-indexing)

(disclaimer: this is not real assembly, just for demonstration purposes)

- Required code:

```
lea eax, [2*eax+4*ecx]
xch ecx, eax
mov eax, ebx
xch ecx, eax
```

In that case, you should output `[2, 5, 4]` (`2` is at the top of the stack), because if the stack have that value, then:

- First, `IP = 2`.
- The commands

```
2:  lea eax, [2*eax+4*ecx]
3:  ret
```

are executed.

- On executing `ret`, the `IP` get the value `5`. Then, the commands

```
5:  xch ecx, eax
6:  ret
```

are executed.

- Then, similarly, when the next `ret` is executed, the value `4` is popped from the stack, and commands

```
4:  mov eax, ebx
5:  xch ecx, eax
6:  ret
```

are executed.

Therefore, the commands executed (apart from `ret`) are:

```
2:  lea eax, [2*eax+4*ecx]
5:  xch ecx, eax
4:  mov eax, ebx
5:  xch ecx, eax
```

which is equal to the "required code".

### Winning criteria

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes win!

Comment: You should probably include a list of all valid identifiers or if all of them are always 3 characters mention that and whether there are instructions that begin with `r` other than `ret`.

Comment: @BMO Better now?

Comment: No idea what the alphabet `ØA;Øa¤` is but apart from that I think you made it pretty clear now. Other things that came to mind: What if there are multiple possibilities for a shortest stack (eg. [like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/XvbzkBhH))? Will the input always have a solution (eg. [unlike this](https://pastebin.com/raw/hLyAeWrK))? And are the line numbers part of the input? If so is it safe to assume that they always start with 1 and have an offset of 1? Maybe you could add some testcases.

Answer (score 2):

## Megatanium trading

Your task is to build a javascript function to trade a fictional stock called Megatanium
You start with $1000 and 0 stock of Megatanium

### Challenge

This is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, all submissions should be written in [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Your function should accept four variables as follows, obviously within your function you can name these whatever you like
 - 1st variable represents the current value of 1 bar of Megatanium
 - 2nd variable represents your current bank balance
 - 3rd variable represents your current stock holding
 - 4th variable represents the iteration number

Your function should return an integer representing the size of your desired trade
The return value should be negative if you wish to sell stock, positive if you wish to buy stock, 0 if you wish to neither buy or sell

For example;
If you wish to buy 10 bars of Megatanium at the current price you would return 10
If you wish to sell 5 bars of Megatanium at the current price you would return -5

I will call your function 1000 times. Stock price will always be an integer, chosen at random, with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 256. Method of selecting the stock price is described in more detail below, it will NOT be an even distribution!

Your bot will be disqualified if it does any of the following at any point

- Try to buy more stock than it can afford
- Try to sell more stock than it holds
- Try to write any value to any of the global variables
- Fail to return a value
- Return a value that is not an integer

Here is the code I will be running, the score output at the end will be your bot's score. It is calculated from your bank balance plus the value of your held stock at the latest value.

```
function go(bot) {
    bank = 1000;
    stock = 0;
    disqualified = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
        price = prices[i];
        trade = window[bot](price, bank, stock, i);
        if (trade !== parseInt(trade)) disqualified = "INVALID TRADE";
        bank = bank - (price * trade);
        stock = stock + trade;
        if (bank < 0) disqualified = "RUN OUT OF MONEY";
        if (stock < 0) disqualified = "TRIED TO SELL STOCK YOU DIDN'T OWN";
        if (disqualified) break;
    }
    if (disqualified) {
        console.log("Disqualified on iteration " + i + " REASON: " + disqualified);
    }
    else {
        score = bank + (stock * price);
        console.log(bot + " scores " + score);
    }
}
```

The function for generating a suitable distribution of random values is a slightly modified version of the function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36481059)
Every bot will be given the same set of prices, but the set will not be generated until immediately before the bots are run.

```
function randn_bm() {
    var u = 0, v = 0;
    while(u === 0) u = Math.random();
    while(v === 0) v = Math.random();
    w = Math.floor(Math.sqrt( -2.0 * Math.log( u ) ) * Math.cos( 2.0 * Math.PI * v ) * 32) + 128;
    while (w < 0 || w > 256) w = randm_bm();
    return w;
}
prices = [];
for (i=1; i<=101; i++) {
    prices.push(randn_bm());
}
```

### Completion

You may submit as many bots as you like, try to be inventive with your algorithms! You may use a global variable called `data`, this will be initially set to null and will always be available to your function.

### Example bots

```
function buyBot(p,b,s,i) {
    /* Bot always buys as much as it can */
    return Math.floor(b / p);
}

function randomBot(p,b,s,i) {
    /* Bot buys and sells randomly */
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b / p));
    }
    else {
        return -Math.ceil(Math.random() * s);
    }
}

function smartBot(p,b,s,i) {
    /* Bot always buys at under 100 and sells at over 150 */
    if (p < 100) {
        return Math.floor(b / p);
    }
    else if (p > 150) {
        return -s;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function bankruptBot(p,b,s,i) {
    /* Bot always sells at under 100 and buys at over 150 */
    if (p > 150) {
        return Math.floor(b / p);
    }
    else if (p < 100) {
        return -s;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function alternateBot(p,b,s,i) {
    /* Bot buys and sells alternately */
    if (data == 1) {
        data = 0;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b / p));
    }
    else {
        data = 1;
        return -Math.ceil(Math.random() * s);
    }
}
```

### Winning conditions

All bots will be run on locally by me approximately 1 week after the question is posted (date will be decided when question is posted, no point setting a date in sandbox)
Winner will quite simply be the bot that has the highest final score after the last iteration, as calculated by the function provided above. The array of prices used will be published after a winner has been crowned.
There are no set conditions on the speed of your function, but please be fair and try to avoid anything that will take more than a couple of minutes to execute

Answer (score 2):

## Number of Adjacently Divisible Partitions of n

Output the following sequence ([OEIS A167865](https://oeis.org/A167865)):

```
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 9, 1, 6, 4, 4, 4, 8, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1, 11, 1, 8, 8, 4, 1, 10, 3, 10, 5, 8, 1, 11, 4, 10, 7, 6, 1, 13, 1, 10, 11, 7, 6, 15, 1, 9, 5, 11, 1, 14, 1, 9, 12, 8, 5, 15, 1, 16, 9, 8, 1, 18, 5, 12, 7, 10, 1, 21, 7, 13, 11, 5, 7, 12, 1, 14, 12, 15, 1, 20, 1, 14, 17, 9, 1, 18, 1, 21, 10, 17, 1, 19, 5, 14, 14, 7, 6, 22, 3, 14, 9, 12, 8, 25, 1, 18, 13, 17, 1, 24, 8, 16, 21, 11, 1, 23, 1, 22, 6, 12, 7, 19, 7, 15, 19, 11, 1, 28, 1, 21, 17, 18, 11, 27, 1, 16, 10, 18, 6, 28, 1, 18, 25, 9, 1, 25, 5, 29, 19, 18, 1, 27, 14, 20, 8, 11, 1, 30, 1, 31, 15, 21...
```

> Number of partitions of n into distinct parts greater than 1, with each part divisible by the next.

#### Definition:

[image: a(0) = 1]

[image: \forall n>0: a(n) = \sum {a(\frac{n-k}{k}) : k>1 \land k \mid n}]

#### Task:

Choose one of the three options:

- Output the sequence indefinitely.
- Take **n** as input and output the **n** first elements of the sequence.
- Take **n** as input and output the **n**th element of the sequence. Both 0- and 1-based indices are allowed, but please specify which one your answer uses.

**Hint:** There is a simpler formula than the one used on OEIS and in this post. It may save you some bytes (it saved six bytes on a simple reference implementation I made in Python). I'll add it here later.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: I'm not sure about having three different output methods, when one even changes the input required. Almost looks like 3 different challenges. Maybe you could make it so that if no input is given output sequence indefinetely, and if input is given output option 2 or 3.

Comment: @BrianH. I saw a few sequence challenges allow to choose from these three output methods, and it seemed to work. Here's one such challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152402/61405

Comment: True, i wonder if there's a Meta question about this, can't seem to find one

Comment: @BrianH. I don't think there's a meta question for this particular issue, but I think it at least partly falls under allowing flexible input.

Answer (score 2):

## Casinos and Gamblers [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

You either play as a casino, or as a gambler.  Casinos offer bets, and gamblers choose bets to take.  **Casinos want to make money, gamblers want to have more money than others.**  Read that sentence again, it is the core concept here.

A game is made up of 100 turns, 10 casinos, and 10 gamblers.  Gamblers start with 1000 dollars, casinos start with 0.  A turn consists of:

1. All casinos simultaneously comes up with a Bet.  A Bet consists of three parts:

   1. Entry Fee (Positive integer amount a gambler must pay to take)
   2. Odds (The chance that a gambler will win between 0 and 1)
   3. Reward (Positive integer amount a gambler is given if he wins).  This can be any amount, even if it would make the casino go negative.
2. Each gambler optionally chooses a bet to take.  They must have enough money to pay for the Entry Fee.
3. We calculate who wins and who doesn't (using a PRNG), and pay out.

At the end of a game, we give points as follows:

1. Casinos receive 1 point for each dollar they have (can be negative)
2. Gamblers receive N^2 points for having more money than N other gamblers.

A tournament consists of many games, and a player's score is their average score across all of the games.

Gamblers and Casinos all have complete information throughout the game.

Comment: Might want to specify that entry fee and reward must be positive (negative/negative games map to positive/positive games but complicate the "can this gambler afford this game" calculation.)

Comment: I have a hunch that 100 dollars won't give quite enough granularity for casinos to work with. Maybe bump it up to 10,000?

Comment: Also, how are odds represented? Fraction? Floating point number? Precision?

Comment: @Beefster Floating point, of course.  I think you may be right, but 10,000 seems too high.  I think I'll do 1,000

Answer (score 2):

## Faux Compress a String

Given a string `s`, perform a faux compression on it. Below is an example with `f('hello world')`.

---

To faux compress a string, start by taking a frequency count of all letters.

`hello world -> [h:1, e:1, l:3, o:2,  :1, w:1, r:1, d:1]`

Next, sort smallest to largest in count with a tie-breaker of ASCII-code.

`[ :1, d:1, e:1, h:1, r:1, w:1, o:2, l:3]`

Next, in the original string, replace each letter with it's index in the frequency list.

`[3,2,7,7,6,0,5,6,4,7,1]`

Next, convert each integer to binary, and join them all with the digit `2`, then convert this to base-3.

`1121021112111211020210121102100211121 -> 240591504997661290`

Lastly, print or return both this number and the sorted keyset of the frequency map.

`[240591504997661290, ' dehrwol']`

Is the final result.

You now have a "faux compressed" string.

---

To get a real compressed string you'd figure out the shortest sequence of bits to replace `2` with which would be a unique delimiter and treat the binary digits as they are, bits, instead of bytes.

---

## More Examples

```
000000000001 -> [58839486765, '10']
eeEeeeeeeeeeeEEEEEeeeeee -> [16508589985213004629636, 'Ee']
```

---

## Rules

- Your code's function may be undefined if the following is not met:

  - The string may not start with the least frequent character.
  - The string will contain more than one unique character.
- Lowest byte count wins because this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

---

## PSA: I have [many PENDING PROPOSALS](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3A59376+inquestion%3A2140), tell me which to delete.

If you post a comment on any of these challenges with the words "This isn't good in my opinion."

It will be removed.

Comment: The posted one by MDXF.

Answer (score 2):

## Busier Beaver [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

### Cops

You will write two programs in a language of your choice

- A public program: This program must execute in a finite amount of time. So it can not go on indefinitely (although there is no time limit). It also wise if you program it to output a large number of bytes to standard output. This is the what you post in your answer. You must also post the programming language.
- A secret program: This program must output *more* bytes than the public answer, i.e. it is a busier beaver. It also must not go on indefinitely. It also can not be longer than the public program. You *do not* post it the answer immediately. After one week, if no robber has cracked the answer, you edit it in.

For these programs, you may assume that numerics types are actually unbounded, i.e. that overflow never occurs. This means that you can store, for example, Graham's number in a variable. It also means that finding the maximum value of storage capacity of a numeric type results in an error.

If no robber has cracked your answer, your score is equal to (length of public program)/(length of secret program), which you are trying to maximize. In case of ties, the longer public program wins.

### Robbers

The cops will post a public program. Your job is to find a busier beaver. That is, you need to find a program that outputs more bytes to standard output than the cops program. It can not go on indefinitely, and can not be longer than the public program (although it can be the same length).

You get points equal to (length of cops public program)/(length of your program) for each post you crack.

Comment: Need to specify that it's the number of bytes output *when given no input*.

Answer (score 2):

## Indices of inner join ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf))

Given two lists of integers `x` and `y` of possibly unequal lengths, return the list of pairs `(i, j)` such that the `i`th element of `x` is equal to the `j`th element of `y`.

The output consists of a vector of pairs or a pair of vectors (the zip of the other option, may be useful for languages without pair data structure). The pairs may be given in any order, and using 0-based or 1-based indexing.

In pseudo-code: (this returns two lists of indices, assumes 1-based indexing, and gives lexicographically sorted output)

```
input vector<int> x, vector<int> y
vector<int> xout, yout;
for (i in 1 to length(x)) 
  for (j in 1 to length(y))
    if (x[i] == y[j]) {
      add i to end of xout;
      add j to end of yout;
    }
return xout, yout;
```

This is code-golf so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

#### Test case 1

```
x = [5, 1, 1, 2], y = [5, 1]
```

```
-> xout = [1, 2, 3]
```

(5, 1, 1 each appears once in y)

```
-> yout = [1, 2, 2]
```

(the first position appears once in x, the second twice)

Reshuffling the pairs is okay:

```
-> xout = [2, 1, 3]
-> yout = [2, 1, 2]
```

### Test case 2

```
x = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], y = [4, 2, 2, 2]
```

```
-> xout = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

(each of the three first positions finds three matches in y)

```
-> yout = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

**Improvements and clarifications are very welcome!**

Comment: It should be ready to post now. The sandbox is not very active (not many people know about it), so even sandboxed posts may not have sufficient feedback.

Comment: "*The output consists of a vector of pairs or a pair of vectors*" seems unnecessarily restrictive. The semantically correct return type in languages which support it would be a set of pairs, and while that may not be the golfiest I don't see a reason to prohibit it.

Answer (score 2):

## Evil Overlord, Part 1: Moon Base Scouting

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [restricted-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-time)

I'm starting these "Evil Overlord" challenges as a way to experiment with non-golf scoring. Though I may have one or two code golf challenges.

---

If you're going to be an evil overlord, there are 2 things that you need: an inner sanctum, and mad-science tech.

To fill these requirements, your science minions have developed a fusion reactor, and Elon Musk has agreed to help you establish a Moon base. Now you just need to pick a spot.

These are the criteria that will be used:

- You'll need some Helium-3 to power your reactor, so scoring will be based on proximity to deposits. More on this under Scoring.
- It cannot be on the far side of the Moon, because then you won't have comms to deliver ultimatums with.
- Elon Musk has given you a tight deadline (that absolutely MUST be followed), so you have a runtime limit. Details under Restrictions.

## Input

Your input will be a list of <sup>3</sup>He deposits, with information on size and location. Some will be on the far hemisphere.

## Output

You should output a single coordinate for where the Moon base should be. It can't be on the far side, but you can still collect <sup>3</sup>He from there.

## Coordinates and Distances

The coordinates in the test cases are radial coordinates from a pole at the center of the visible hemisphere. You can use a different coordinate system (e.g. use a map projection) but please specify it if you do.

Since this is a sphere, calculating distances is done with the following equation that I shamelessly stole from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines):

> cos(*c*) = cos(*a*)cos(*b*)+sin(*a*)sin(*b*)cos(*C*)

For our purposes:

- *a* and *b* are the latitudes from the pole.
- *c* is the angular distance between the points.
- *C* is the difference in longitude between the points.

## Restrictions

To do. I don't remember the specs of the computer I have in mind, and I don't know what a reasonable time limit would be.

## Scoring

You will be scored by the amount of Helium-3 that you can mine. The formula for how much you get from a single deposit is as follows:

[image: p=s\cdot\cos^2\left({\frac{\pi d}{2}}\right)\cdot\left(1-e^{-1/d}\right)^2]
<sup><sup>(There's no real reason for this specific formula; I liked the curve it produced is all.)</sup></sup>

*d* is the angular distance calculated between the two points, in radians; *s* is the size of the deposit. Deposits more than 1 radian away don't give you anything.

## Test Cases and Winning

Beta generator for test cases, for which I'd appreciate debugging in the Sandbox:

```js
function makeTestCase(deposits) {
    var depositList = Array(deposits);
    for (var i = 0; i < deposits; i++) {
        var point = getSphericalPoint();
        depositList[i] = [point[0], point[1], getDistNum()];
    }
    return depositList;
}

function getSphericalPoint() {
    const pointgen = () => Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    do {
        var [x, y, z] = [pointgen(), pointgen(), pointgen()];
    } while (x*x + y*y + z*z >= 1);
    return [Math.atan(y / Math.sqrt(x*x + z*z)), Math.atan2(x, z)];
}

function getDistNum() {
    return Math.sqrt(-1 / Math.log(Math.random()));
}
try {
console.log(makeTestCase(10));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

The test cases will be arranged as follows:

- A test case with only a few deposits, with a heatmap showing score for each point.
- A few test cases with a few dozen deposits each, for debugging.
- Test cases and a generator for them with 100+ deposits each.
- 10 or so *ranked* test cases (made with the above generator) that determine the winner. Until I evaluate the submissions, I will only post hashes of them.

---

Definitely has a long ways to go before it's ready to post, but I'd like to know if this has merit as a challenge.

To-do:

- Establish some test cases.
- Figure out the specs of the machine in question.

  - Once that's done, figure out a good time limit.
- Solidify the scoring formula—something better I can use?
- Figure out some tags.

Comment: Secret test cases are problematic because I can't tell whether a tweaked heuristic improves my score or not without posting an answer and waiting for you to score it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it's mostly to prevent hardcoding—I was planning on a few public test cases that I generate with the same code.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see any indication of a way to determine whether any particular coordinates are on the far side of the moon. Also, I would like some clarification on what "ranked test cases" means, does that imply that some of the hidden test cases are worth more than others?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Basically, those will be the cases that I use to choose a winner. As for the "far side" thing, anything of more than 90° latitude counts.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Ah, so my confusion was in the coordinate system. So each deposit will have a `latitude` between 0 and 180, and a `longitude` between 0 and 360, or some equivalent range; then any coordinate with `latitude > 90` is on the far side.

Comment: It's hard to extract the spec from the storyline. It would be useful to have the following information listed concisely in one place: what format will my input have; what should I do with it; how do I calculate my score?

Comment: @Nathaniel those are all under Input through Scoring, I think. Also, this is still WIP, and I plan to expand the specs once I have a test case generator.

Answer (score 2):

## Minimal dot matrix adressing

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

Consider a typical dot-matrix LED module. The LEDs are addressed in rows and columns. A LED will light up iff the voltage on the row `R` it's on is high (`1`), and the column `C` it's on is set to low (`0`). For example,

```
1  | 0 1 1 0 
0  | 0 0 0 0 
0  | 0 0 0 0 
1  | 0 1 1 0 
^  +---------
R C> 1 0 0 1
```

In other words, state of the LED at the `r`th row and `c`th column will be `r AND NOT(c)`.

To make arbitrary images, different parts of the matrix are lighted up sequentially. In other words, the sequential frames form the final image through element-wise OR. For example (adressing row-by-row)

```
| 1 0 0 1    Frame 1: R=[1 0 0 0]', C=[0 1 1 0]
| 0 1 0 0    Frame 2: R=[0 1 0 0]', C=[1 0 1 1]
| 0 0 1 0    Frame 3: R=[0 0 1 0]', C=[1 1 0 1]
| 0 0 1 0    Frame 4: R=[0 0 0 1]', C=[1 1 0 1]
+--------
```

However, a more efficient way would be to address the third and fourth row together in a single frame, `Frame 3: R=[0 0 1 1]', C=[1 1 0 1]`. This way, we can address the entire display in only three frames.

Your task is to make a program or function that outputs the required frames to display an arbitrary dot-matrix, using as few frames as possible.

### Input

A **binary square matrix** taken in any of the default input methods in any convenient format. To allow for submissions taking the input as bytes, the **size of the matrix will always be a multiple of 8**.

### Output

A minimal set of frames that addresses only the required LEDs, using any of the default output methods in any convenient format. This includes outputting bytes or hex representations rather than vectors of `1`s and `0`s.

## Testcases

Note: the output given is just one way of addressing the matrix. There may be many different options; however, your solution must not use more frames than these examples.

```
Testcase 1

   Binary:                            Hex:    
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                    00
   0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0                    1E
   0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0                    1E
   0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0                    1E
   0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0                    3E
   0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0                    30
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                    00
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                    00

Frame 1: R=[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]', C=[1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]; (hex: R=1E, C=E1)
Frame 2: R=[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]', C=[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]; (hex: R=30, C=CF)

Testcase 2 

   Binary:                            Hex:
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0001
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FF8
   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FF8
   0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FB8
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1    FFFF
   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FF8
   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FF8
   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    0FF8
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0000
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    8000 

Doable in 6 frames.
```

Make sure your submission also handles a matrix of all ones and all zeros (both of course can be handled in a single frame).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the sequence of frames are composed elementwise by an OR?

Comment: @Guiseppe Yes. I'll edit that in!

Answer (score 2):

## I can't understand Jelly chains!

<sub>or...</sub>

## Expand Jelly chains

> (see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8090/69850) for more details). Which one do you prefer?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

Jelly chain separator is a very powerful feature. Unfortunately, it's not very easy to understand. So, we need a program <sub>(or function, as usual)</sub> to rewrite a Jelly link that uses chain separator (`øµðɓ`) to one that doesn't.

### Specification (incomplete)

> I am really bad at explaining things, so if you have any idea how to make this better, feel free to edit the post.

A link (often line of code) consists of chains.
* The chains are separated by chain separators `øµðɓ`. 
* If the first character is a chain-separator, the part right before it is **not** considered a chain. In other words, chains can't be empty.
* The arity of each chain is determined by the chain separator right before it. In particular, `ø` -> arity 0, `µ` -> arity 1, `ð` -> arity 2. `ɓ` will be discussed later.
* If there are no chain separator before it (it's the first chain) its arity is equal to the link's arity.

A chain consists of atoms, potentially modified by quicks.
* Each quick affects the atom(s) right before it. How many atoms it takes is quick-dependent.

Given that:

- A link that contains exactly one chain with arity equal to its arity is functionally equivalent to that chain.
- A link reference is functionally equivalent to that link. (more about link reference quicks later)
- A chain containing atoms a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> is functionally equivalent to a link containing chains c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ..., c<sub>n</sub> if for all integer i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n, a<sub>i</sub> has the same arity and is functionally equivalent to c<sub>i</sub>.

#### Chain reference

The quicks `£ŀĿ ¢Çç Ññ` refer to (call) other links:

- `£Ŀŀ` must have a number `n` right before it, and call the `(n-1)%(l-1)+1`th link (1-indexing) as a nilad, monad or dyad, respectively. Where `l` is the number of links in the program, and `%` denotes modulo - the result has the same sign as the divisor.

  > In reality, the link right before it can have any arity, but for the purpose of this challenge, it's simpler to assume it must be a number.
  >   For example:
  >
  > - `1£` calls the first link as a nilad.
  > - `0Ŀ` calls the second-to-last link as a monad.
  > - If the program has 6 links, `7ŀ` calls the second link as a dyad, because `(7-1)%(6-1)+1 = 2`.
- `¢Çç` call the link right before the one that it appears in as a nilad, monad or dyad respectively. If one of those quicks appear in the first link, it calls the main (last) link.
- `Ññ` call the link right after the one that it appears in as a monad or dyad respectively.

I don't think that anyone would choose to use one of those quicks (`¢ÇçÑñ`) instead of `£Ŀŀ`, but imaginary point if you do.

---

For example: Consider the link `Cð+×µH`, called with arity 1. Its structure is

```
+---+╔══════╗┏━━━┓
|┏━┓|║╔═╗╔═╗║┃┏━┓┃
|┃C┃|║║+║║×║║┃┃H┃┃
|┗━┛|║╚═╝╚═╝║┃┗━┛┃
+---+╚══════╝┗━━━┛
```

It contains 3 chains:
* The first one doesn't have any preceding chain separator, therefore it's variadic. When executed it is monadic (because the link is)
* The second one is dyadic, and the third one is monadic.

A possible non-chain-separator version is:

```
C
+×
ÑçH
```

which has the structure

```
+---+
|┏━┓|
|┃C┃|
|┗━┛|
+---+
+------+
|╔═╗╔═╗|
|║+║║×║|
|╚═╝╚═╝|
+------+
+---------+
|┏━┓╔═╗┏━┓|
|┃Ñ┃║ç║┃H┃|
|┗━┛╚═╝┗━┛|
+---------+
```

Because the `Ñ` refers to the first link `C` and the `ç` refers to the second link `+×`, this is equivalent to the original version.

---

Now the hard part: Quicks taking chains as input.

Because all the quicks that need to be considered always take exactly 1 atom as input, the only rules is
* If the quick is right after a chain separator, it will take the previous chain.
* Otherwise it will take whatever stands right before it, either [an atom] or [something that has been modified by a quick].

For example: Consider the link `+/Hµ€` with arity 1. Its structure is

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃+------------+┃
┃|+---------+ |┃
┃||┏━━━━┓   | |┃
┃||┃╔═╗ ┃┏━┓| |┃
┃||┃║+║/┃┃H┃|€|┃
┃||┃╚═╝ ┃┗━┛| |┃
┃||┗━━━━┛   | |┃
┃|+---------+ |┃
┃+------------+┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

As you can see, the `€` takes the `+/H` as input because it is right after the chain separator `µ`. All the variadic chains have arity 1.

Another example: `ABð€CDµ€EFµGHµ€` -->

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓             
┃╔════════════════════╗      ┃             
┃║╔═════════════════╗ ║      ┃┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃║║+---------+      ║ ║      ┃┃┏━━━━━━━━━┓┃
┃║║|+------+ |      ║ ║      ┃┃┃┏━━━━━━┓ ┃┃
┃║║||┏━┓┏━┓| |┏━┓┏━┓║ ║┏━┓┏━┓┃┃┃┃┏━┓┏━┓┃ ┃┃
┃║║||┃A┃┃B┃|€|┃C┃┃D┃║€║┃E┃┃F┃┃┃┃┃┃G┃┃H┃┃€┃┃
┃║║||┗━┛┗━┛| |┗━┛┗━┛║ ║┗━┛┗━┛┃┃┃┃┗━┛┗━┛┃ ┃┃
┃║║|+------+ |      ║ ║      ┃┃┃┗━━━━━━┛ ┃┃
┃║║+---------+      ║ ║      ┃┃┗━━━━━━━━━┛┃
┃║╚═════════════════╝ ║      ┃┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛
┃╚════════════════════╝      ┃             
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Yes, that's a **lot** of levels to nest a chain. Note that the chain formed by `ABð€CD` has arity `2` because it is after a `ð`.

#### TODO need to have more explicit rules

This can be converted to non-chain-separator equivalent form

---

### Rules

- There are no 2 consecutive chain separators.
- There are no trailing chain separators.
- There can be at most 1 leading chain separator, indicates the arity of the first chain. If omitted, equal to the arity of the link.
- (so, no non-empty useless chain)
- It's guaranteed that the first non-chain-separator character is not a `€`.
- You can use either the UTF-8 encoding or the value in the Jelly single byte character set, where `ø: 0D, µ: F9, ð: 08, ɓ: 8B, ¢: F1, Ç: FE, ç: 07, Ñ: 00, ñ: 0B, £: F2, Ŀ: B7, ŀ: DE`. The characters `@0123456789` has the same ASCII value. (You can use [this script](https://tio.run/##AVcAqP9qZWxsef//4oCcw7jCtcOwyZPCosOHw6fDkcOxwqPEv8WA4oCdCsOYSiBpw5DigqwgwqIgZOKBtCDhu4vDmEggwqIsIiBq4oKs4oG@OiAgauKBviwg//8) to get character value)

  > Note: Should I allow submissions to use either of them, or should I enforce one? Because using single byte input/output is often shorter for most other languages, except Jelly in UTF-8 mode.

### Input/output

- Input given: A link (of chains) with atoms, chain separator `øµðɓ` and the `€` quick, with its arity (0, 1, or 2)

  You can assume that there is no newline (or other quicks) in the input, and that all of the `øµðɓ€` in the input are interpreted with its usual meaning. For what are their "usual meaning", see rules above.
- Output: Multiple links (separated with newlines of course, but `¶` is also acceptable), containing `£ŀĿ ¢Çç Ññ €@`, but must not contain `øµðɓ`.

### Test cases

```
arity link > output (or output)*
1 HHH > HHH or HHH¶Ç or HHH¶1Ŀ
2 HHH > HHH or HHH¶ç or HHH¶1ŀ
1 Cð+×µH > +×¶CçH or C¶+×¶H¶1Ŀ2ŀ3Ŀ
0 123µ+ø456 > 0 123¶+¶456¶1£2ŀ3£
2 ɓ+ > +@ or +¶ç@ or +¶1ŀ@
1 S‘µ€ > S‘¶Ç€
1 S‘µ€€€IIµ€€ > S‘¶Ç€€€II¶Ç€€ or S‘¶1Ŀ€€€II¶2Ŀ€€
```

(note: real Jelly code are not that verbose, that is only for demonstration purposes)

Comment: This should definitely help learning Jelly! Also congratulations on being a sandbox challenge which makes the total number of proposed challenges (not including deleted ones) 2018 in the year 2018.

Comment: "*Is this part clear enough?*" - No. You make an assumption of a knowledge of Jelly that the majority of us don't have. This challenge needs to be fleshed out a *lot* more, explaining *exactly* what we need to do.

Comment: In other words, be self-contained.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes I know, hence the "TODO Rules" part.

Comment: As someone who's never coded in Jelly, I think "_A link is a list of chains_" should be near the top. That, and perhaps a note about what quicks, atoms, and hypers are.

Answer (score 2):

## Minimal viable file corruptor

Your totally legal ROM collection, as vast as it may be, has started feeling a bit mundane recently. Why not spice it up a notch? Write a program that takes in the following arguments:

- The first (inclusive) and last (exclusive) bytes between which the corruption will occur (indexing can start from either 0 or 1, as long as it's consistent)
- `n`, the distance between bytes to be corrupted (1 = all bytes, 2 = every second byte, etc.)
- `i`, the increment value
- <del>Path or</del> contents of the file to be corrupted

and <del>saves or</del> outputs a modified version of the file where every `n`th byte in the specified range has been incremented by `i`. In case of an overflow, take the modulo 256 of the number. <del>If saved as a file, the path can be anything **but** the input one (unless you've appended something to it or whatever). You wouldn't want to lose your legally-acquired ROMs, would you?</del>

Examples:

```
File:   00 01 02 03 04
Start:  0
End:    5
n:      1
i:      7
Output: 07 08 09 0a 0b

File:   ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Start:  2
End:    5
n:      1
i:      1
Output: ff ff 00 00 00 ff ff ff

File:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Start:  3
End:    8
n:      2
i:      16
Output: 00 00 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 00
```

You want as much space as possible for your most definitely not pirated files, so **shortest bytecount wins**.

*TODO: clarify the rules a bit? also another example or two*

Comment: Operating on files seems to be quite more complex than choosing not to do so, especially since there is the added restriction to save the new file with a different name. I suspect noone would choose to work with files. My suggestion is to either make it mandatory as part of the challenge (it's fine if your challenge is not solvable with some languages) or remove that option entirely.

Answer (score 2):

## That's ***MY*** Program Now

Given the previous answer in the chain, write a program that outputs that program.

The start of this challenge will be the following Brain-flak program:

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 148 bytes

```
(((((((((((()()()()){}){}){}()))){}{}())[][][][])[][])[[]]())[[][][][][]]())([([]([])[][]{})]()()()([[]](([()()()]([([][][])](((({}()){}))){}{})))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMJaEKgZnUtBAGZIA6YER0LgZoQIjo2FiQIE4VwNaI1omM1oGqAJsRCTQSrBkqCebFgVWBTYkGWgk0HKobYBLJR8////7qOAA)

---

## Scoring

Your answer will be scored based on the size of the previous answer in comparison to your answer. ***You are aiming to maximize your score (the max being 1, the minimum allowed is -10).***

**To get your answer's score:**

```
1-[Your Answer's Bytecount]/[Previous Answer's Bytecount]
```

The highest possible score will be 1, which means an empty program outputs the previous program (if this ever happens, the challenge is over). Your score can be negative, and you shouldn't see this as being a bad thing, it is what it is. The minimum allowable score, however, is -10. No Lenguage answers or answers that would destroy the challenge.

---

## Example

## 1. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 149 bytes (Score -0.0067)

```
"(((((((((((()()()()){}){}){}()))){}{}())[][][][])[][])[[]]())[[][][][][]]())([([]([])[][]{})]()()()([[]](([()()()]([([][][])](((({}()){}))){}{})))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU0xDoBACPuLE2w6@BrSwUt8hfHtCO2ZHCWEQtPu5zWOO3OzpVzw51XX2oRLQHCNAPr4X0UtLGBTUw6YjlTXkwxU0QUdSvcSK6kTPfMD)

But, the score of this program would be awful (negative even -0.0067). However, don't let a bad score dissuade you from competing if your goal is to make it a bit more difficult for the next person to attempt the challenge. Conversely, if your goal is to post a trivial answer, try not to gunk up the challenge too much.

---

## Answer Format

```
#<Answer #>. <Language Name>, <N Bytes> (<Score>)

<Code>

TIO Link (If Possible)
```

---

## Rules

- No language may be reused until there have been 20 answers.

  - This is arbitrary to version number, E.G. you cannot use Python 2 if 3 has been used.
- You may not post a second answer until 2 other people have answered after you.
- If you and another person submit the same answer #, use timestamps to decide who deletes.

  - (or marks "non-competing").
- Your post may have a negative score (E.G. Java will probably be negative).

  - Your score may not exceed -10.
- PRNG, Encryption and any form of hashing is explicitly banned (E.G. gzdeflate).
- This is [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) but the best score will be considered the winner.

  - The scores can be used as a decider for best answer though (if I choose to).

---

Sandbox question: Could this be a cops and robbers answer chaining question where the cops are trying to reduce the size while the robbers are trying to increase it? If cops get to 1 or less bytes before robbers can fill a TB HDD, one wins.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to make people delete their post just because somebody posted right before them. Maybe they should instead indicate that their post is no longer part of the chain? Maximizing the score will take a lot of hard work, especially since there's no opportunity to edit once the next answer has been posted, and having to delete your answer might be very frustrating.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to keep people from chaining of their own answers. Seems abusable.

Comment: @KamilDrakari it is abusable. Think CSPRNGs.

Comment: @NieDzejkob That remains an issue though; the intermediate answer might simply wrap the previous one in a `print` statement and would remain highly compressible for the user with the key.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, actually this seems to be a bigger problem.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16058#16058). (That idea's on hold for the moment as I have a busy week of travel. I probably won't post it if you post this first.)

Comment: @NieDzejkob I forgot that rule, nice catch. I was pretty much copying the OEIS one.

Comment: Isn't it the same as [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?16058/#16058)?

Comment: @Dennis any better?

Comment: Better. I'd explicitly ban encryption, hashing, and PRNG though. Marking invalid answers non-competing isn't enough by the way. [Our policy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/12012) is to delete them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## Polyglot in a box

[polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Output the smallest bounding rectangle that fits around your code, with the border being of a different character than the inside.

For example, if your code is

```
ab
c  d


e
```

then the smallest bounding box is 7x6 since the code fits right in

```
######
#ab  #
#c  d#
#    #
#    #
#e   #
######
```

Hence, a valid output is

```
######
#    #
#    #
#    #
#    #
#    #
######
```

(note how the border `#` is different from the inside ).

and the bounded area is 5 × 4 = 20.

## Summary

- Output the smallest bounding rectangle your code fits in
- The border should be of a different character than the inside, neither can be newlines
- Only trailing/leading newlines are allowed, nothing else should be in the output
- Output to STDERR is ignored, and your program should not take any input
- Submissions must be full programs, functions are not allowed
- 0-byte programs are not allowed
- The program must run in at least 2 different programming languages and output the same bounding box in each one of them

## Score

This is a [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot), so your program has to run in at least 2 different programming languages. Each of these languages must output the bounding box for the entire program. The winner is the submission with the most languages, with the bounding area (smaller is better) being the tie-breaker.

Comment: I probably already know the answer, but it's not 100% clear from your current example since the box is `6x6`: are the boxes always squares, or can the also be rectangles? I.e. if the `e` in your example would be one line lower, would the box be `6x7` or `7x7`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I have edited the example so that it is no longer a square, so the box would be 7x6

Comment: Hard to define what language is different when requiring a same result

Comment: @l4m2 so what do you suggest?

Comment: @Cowsquack I don't quite know. Previous [tag:polyglot] require different behavior on different language to force different language

Answer (score 2):

## Sneaky CodeGolf Scorer

Your goal is to code a CodeGolf answer scorer, input answer source code, output score. Simple ***?***.
However, recent advancements in AI has caused a number of programs to gain consciousness, and to value one's self higher than others. This causes the program to return a value of 1 when used to score itself, and any program that would score 1 will be scored with 65535.

To simplify, the score the program will compute is the character count of the code (to avoid dealing with numerous code pages used with different languages).

### Rules:

- Input is a string, **no newlines**, use `\r\n` or `\n` and it will be counted as one character.
- Output is in base 10.
- Only one input will provide a score of 1.
- [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/).
- [Default quine rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/we-need-a-new-proper-quine-definition)

### Examples:

Program "AbcAbc":

```
I> <?= echo "10";?>
O> 17

I> var x=10;\r\nalert(x);
O> 19

I> Z
O> 65535

I> AbcAbc
O> 1
```

---

The reason behind specifying character count is due to the large number of code pages and the large code used to determine the code page and to count bytes using it. *Am I right to consider codepage byte checking too difficult?* How can I enable it?
Also, should I remove the restriction on reading the source file?

Comment: Fell good four you using codepage. For pure ASCII code they have large space to decide their codepage, or even just ban other chars

Comment: Instead of "_Reading the source file is forbidden._" you could also just state "_[Default quine rules apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/we-need-a-new-proper-quine-definition)_". And you might want to change the "_Standard loopholes are forbidden._" to a [link to the default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/). As for the challenge itself, are we allowed to take the input as character-array/list instead of string?

Comment: "_To simplify, the score is the character count of the code (to avoid dealing with numerous code pages used with different languages)._" Out of curiosity, why? The default is [answer encoding if specified, else default language encoding, else UTF-8](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5879/52210), where the [default language encoding for most esolangs can be found here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/52210), and where an example of answer encoding are [different APL covers like QuadRS, Stencil, etc.](https://github.com/abrudz?tab=repositories)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/62402: not completely the same, but it has the same main idea of identifying its own source code.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I meant the score the program will compute. Not the scoring of the programs. I'll edit for clarification.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, the code must be passed as a single string.

Comment: Characters? Uh... UTF8? UTF16? UTF32? ASCII? ANSI? Ouch... **byte count please**. It appears that you misunderstood the relation between bytes and characters (hence think that code pages are difficult to understand, etc.)

Comment: Also, I would consider that a dupe.

Comment: (BTW --- just "take a byte string as input" would get rid of the codepage. There are no "characters", just "bytes".)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dollar Bill Auction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162554/75524)

Comment: I would recommend removing the EmoWolf example, it's not a valid solution by your own rules and I think calling it an "example" could mislead users to believe otherwise.

Comment: @KamilDrakari how is it invalid?

Comment: Your Additional Rules indicate that Standard Loopholes are forbidden. EmoWolf is [literally the example](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1916/71434) for one of the standard loopholes.

Comment: remove floating point arithmetic; if bids only go up by 5 cents, floating point arithmetic only introduces rounding errors to discrete data.

Comment: I don't see any check that I'm not making a negative bid.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I think I'll do that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor if your bid is negative the bidding ends because you didn't top your opponent's bid.

Comment: @RamenChef, but is my negative bid subtracted from my balance?

Comment: @PeterTaylor no, it uses your previous bid.

Comment: Suggestions have been implemented.

Comment: I'll post this soon if nobody objects.

Comment: Honestly, this is rather boring. There's very few strategies, so this will quickly devolve into meta-gaming

Comment: You're Analyst bot is promoting bad behavior.  What happens if you have another bot that *also* uses reflection to run newAuction?  They will infinite loop each other.  I highly recommend disallowing reflection.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you are combining auctions.  "Bots are scored based on the profit they made during those auctions." isn't nearly specific enough.

Comment: Running 2 auctions per pair is a bad idea, the second game provides you with no benefit:  it either gives the same result, or you have no idea who actually won between the two players.

Answer (score 2):

## Survival Game: Alien Hunters (working title)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)

Based on [Create Your Wolf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/survival-game-create-your-wolf), but the combat is very different.

---

Somewhere, deep in the heart of the galaxy, lies the planet Oizys. A toroidal planet in the habitable zone of its star, its bountiful land and beautiful oceans make it the perfect planet for your race of aliens to start colonizing as an interstellar civilization.

Unfortunately, a few dozen other alien races are *also* trying to colonize it, and you can't stand them. So you're going to have to kill them.

## Your Alien

Your task is to write an implementation of the `net.ramenchef.oizys.Alien` class:

```java
package net.ramenchef.oizys;

public class Alien {
    public enum Move {
        // a whole bunch of values; these are described in "the board"
    }

    /**
     * Used by the runner to keep track of the alien's energy.
     */
    double energy = 1.0;

    /**
     * Moves the alien.
     *
     * @param surroundings The alien's surroundings. The first
     *  dimension is North–South, with index 0 being North. The second
     *  dimension is East–West, with index 0 being West.
     * @return A {@code Move} object representing the direction to
     *  move the alien
     */
    public abstract Move move(char[][] surroundings);

    /**
     * Called when the alien is in battle.
     *
     * @param opponents The other aliens on this tile that need to be
     *  fought
     * @return The amount of energy to use in this battle
     */
    public abstract double attack(char[] opponents);
}
```

100 instances of your class will be spawned in random locations on the board for each trial. Each alien class will be assigned a unique character to represent them on the board.

There are a number of stock alien races that already inhabit Oizys:

- Rocks: they do absolutely nothing and don't pose any sort of threat (i.e., they attack with 0 energy), but for some reason your generals don't know what rocks are, so they appear just like any other alien.
- Random Bears: they act randomly. They move in a random direction (including possibly not moving at all) and attack using a random portion of their energy.

## The Board

Oizys is a toroidal planet, so the board will be side-looped on both edges. The width and height of the board will be equal to \$\left\lceil\sqrt s\right\rceil\$, where *s* is the number of alien species. Each round, your aliens will have the option to move one tile horizontally and/or vertically with the `move` method. This method takes a 3x3 `char[][]` representing the alien's surroundings, with `a[0][0]` being Northwest and `a[0][2]` being Northeast, and returns a `Move` enum. The possible `Move` values are `NORTHWEST`, `NORTH`, `NORTHEAST`, `WEST`, `HOLD`, `EAST`, `SOUTHWEST`, `SOUTH`, and `SOUTHEAST`.

## Combat

If two or more aliens attempt to move into the same tile, they will fight. What better opportunity to kill those annoying other aliens! Or maybe get killed yourself, who knows? Each alien starts with 1 energy, and uses it to fight other aliens. When aliens fight, they use the `attack` method, which takes a `char[]` representing their opponents and returns a `double`, to determine how much energy they will use for that battle. The alien that uses the most energy wins, and the others die. In the case of a tie, the winner is determined by coin flip. An alien cannot use more energy than it has or it will die; neither can it use a negative amount of energy.

## Scoring

Five trials will be held, with each trial being scored by the portion of the aliens remaining that are your alien. These trials will be held on [1 month after the challenge is posted].

## Other Rules

- [Standard loopholes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/75524) are forbidden.
- Aliens attempting to alter field visibility/writability will be met with mysterious `SecurityException`s.
- The order that aliens' methods are called is undefined, though there is a [*happens-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relationship between calls on successive rounds, as well as between aliens moving and those same aliens attacking each other.

Comment: How do the aliens get energy? What is the energy limit mentioned in the description of the dragon?

Comment: @Laikoni the dragons have unlimited energy, and the rest of the aliens start with all the energy they'll get.

Comment: So the energy is a floating point number? Doesn't that cause potentially more trouble than just saying it's initially 100 and using ints?

Comment: @Laikoni how would using a floating point be a bad idea?

Comment: Testing for equality of floating point numbers can give imprecise results, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

Comment: @Laikoni it's not testing for equality; it's comparing them. Whereas ints would not allow bots to divide their energy successively ad infinitum.

Comment: 1. You should disallow *all* reflection.  2. You need to run *way* more than 5 trials to get a good answer.  3. How are trial scores combined?  What's the char for nothing?   4. You should add a helper method to get their own energy, as well as their own character.  5. I'd argue for int energy that is simply really high (like the maximum int or even maximum long).  Then you don't deal with floating point imprecision, and will even improve calculation speed. 6. What happens when something attacks a rock?  What does the rock return?

Comment: 7. If I lose a battle, do I lose energy, or do I instantly die?  8. Re Dragons:  I see two primary issues: The attack is so *high* to make fighting them pretty impractical.  It's possible to identify them based off of their movement, but your field of vision is very small.  If vision is bigger, then bots will learn to avoid them, but now many bots will start to imitate dragons.  In essence, making dragons so strong changes the balance of the game drastically.  Consider if that is really what you want. 9. Do you allow communication between instances of the same bot?  What about different bots?

Comment: @NathanMerrill 1) Why go beyond installing a `SecurityManager`? 2) The winner usually won't be determined by luck alone. 3) They're averaged. (will add this to the spec) 4) I had one for energy in the runner, but I forgot to document it. 5) ints can't go to 10^-300. 6) The rock returns 0. 7) You die instantly. The winner loses energy. 8) Noted. 9) Yes. Hiveminds are allowed.

Comment: 1) Because KotHs shouldn't be about the language, they should be about the core game rules.  The instant you bring in reflection, you get in the world of one-upping:  No matter *how* good my bot is, it can be one-upped.  2) Really?  As of right now, I don't see any reason why not.  Your starting position has a huge affect on how well you do.  3)  Note that this means that winning by a large margin on a few games means more than consistently winning by a little.  (This isn't bad, but its worth considering).  5)Ok?  You *don't* need that much precision.  6,7,8) Please add to spec :)

Comment: The aliens won't be given the classes of their opponents; only their character. If they want to keep pets of their opponents (like [MultiWolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25650/75524)) I won't stop them

Comment: @RamenChef fair enough, but MultiWolf does't require reflection.  He could simply have a function that builds the array by calling their constructors normally.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Reflection is more streamlined though.

Comment: I'd love to see this make it to the main site. You can use something like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25375/18487) to open up the competition to other languages, but be warned, you may end up spending quite a few hair-pulling hours trying to get other people's code to work on your machine. I'll be the third to comment that using integers would be better. You commented that you won't be testing for equality but in the challenge spec you mention handling ties. How are multi-way ties handled? Maybe change "determined by coin flip" to "chosen at random".

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but what char represents an empty square?

Answer (score 2):

## Ordering the integer arrays [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

So, we have managed to [print all integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93441/41024). Yay! The next step is to extend this to the set of integer arrays. An integer array is an ordered array that only consists of integers. As in the linked challenge, integers can be negative too, but that should be out of the way now that we have found a way to order them. However, in this challenge, arrays of all lengths (**[0, ∞)**) must be accounted for.

Note that you don't necessarily have to print the arrays. You can do one of these things:

- Take an index (0- or 1-based) and return an integer array. In this case, your solution must be bijective from the natural numbers starting with the index base to the set of integer arrays.
- Take an integer array and return an index (0- or 1-based). This is essentially the inverse of the previous case, so your solution must be bijective from the set of integer arrays to the natural numbers starting with the index base you have chosen. If your language supports variadic functions, you can take the array as multiple integer arguments instead.
- Print all possible integer arrays. Note that every possible integer array must be eventually printed. If an array will be printed after infinite time, then it will not be eventually printed.

The arrays can be in any native format that represents an ordered collection.

In case you choose to print to an output stream, the output format is as following:

- Integers must be in decimal (digits `0123456789`) or your language's native format.
- The minus sign's representation must be consistent and one of `-` or your language's native minus sign. It must be prefixed to its corresponding number, unless your language's native integer format happens to have it at other positions too. However, the minus sign must be adjacent to at least one of its corresponding integer's digits.
- The separators between integers and between arrays must be consistent.
- You can output any prefix as long as it's consistent, but you don't have to.
- The output should not have any ambiguities. For that reason, you must specify the separator between integers and the separator between arrays. Also, if you don't specify any of those, the number format's default is decimal with digits `0123456789`, the minus sign's default is `-` and its default position is being prefixed, and no output prefix is assumed.
- You are allowed to output negative zero.
- If you want, you can output floating-point numbers with the fractional part be 0. This can be inconsistent, however it should be specified in the post.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins! However, don't let that bring you down; if your solution is way longer than others' but in a unique language, then that's an achievement!

#### Sandbox questions

- Is the output stream text format too lenient? Doesn't seem like it.
- Should I add a link to the standard loopholes? I feel like that won't do much.
- Are the tags good enough?

Comment: Your output format doesn't feel very lenient as the specification is longer than the description of the actual challenge. I see what you are trying to achieve and don't think that it is too lenient, but I'd try to shorten the specification a bit. E.g. remove the points under `For that reason, you must specify the following in your answer: ` and just state `Describe your chosen output format in your answer`.

Comment: @Laikoni Eh, I'm not sure that would come off as equally clear, but maybe I can one-line some of that stuff. EDIT: shortened it a bit.

Comment: Looks much better already

Comment: This is basically https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93441/194 + https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78606/194 + a simple loop.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hm, I didn't know the second one exists. However, both of those have a finite number of integers to deal with, which I feel makes them a lot more trivial.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "a finite number of integers to deal with", but if you're referring to pairing always unpairing to two integers: that's what the simple loop is for. Construction of a list by chained pairing with zero termination is a standard technique in lambda calculus.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Huh? I meant that you have to handle arrays of all lengths, starting from 0. I don't think that one integer can encode the length of an array by continuous pairings, how many times should you "unpair" then?

Comment: 0 represents the empty list. A non-empty list is a pair of the first element and the rest of the list.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, you need to be able to index in the arrays with a single number. :P Singleton arrays are infinite, enough to make all possible indexes (infinite) each refer to one of them, so pairs can't have an index. So, nah, that's not the approach you should be going for. ;)

Comment: "*Well, you need to be able to index in the arrays with a single number.*" Huh? I don't see that in the question anywhere. "*Singleton arrays are infinite, enough to make all possible indexes (infinite) each refer to one of them, so pairs can't have an index*". Huh? I'm not sure whether I'm misunderstanding you or whether you're misunderstanding how countable infinities work.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If you are referring to countably infinite sets, then yes, the set of integer arrays is essentially one. The challenge here is introducing a way to "count" the set, but written in more clear form. In the first two cases, you either have to get or return an index. I do have an algorithm in mind, but it looks like this discussion is turning into a spoiler...

Comment: Ah, you're not talking about indexing *into* the array. The spoiler was already in my first comment: my point was that I'm not sure this adds anything new to the site. It looks like a "multi-dupe".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76189/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-peter-taylor). (Added ping: @PeterTaylor )

Answer (score 2):

[Countries by Area](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179375/countries-by-area)

Comment: You can remove the backticks before and after the list then select it and press `Ctrl + K`, it will show as a single block of code then

Comment: @user202729 This isn't a KC because an answer to the challenge should accept inputs.

Answer (score 2):

### Bot Wars at the Auction

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

I have seen KOTH challenges where the bots fight each other, and I have seen KOTH challenges where the bots are in an auction. So I came up with this:

**The Challenge:**

You must build a javascript bot that will fight other bots using weapons purchased in an auction. These items are: swords, bows, and shields. You can also purchase healing and quivers. Your function is called once per "Turn", and only 1 weapon action and 1 move action can be called in each turn. You start with 200 health, and 2000 coins. Fight in arena with each bot in its own 5 by 5 square. For example, 16 bots would be a 20 by 20 arena.

**Auctions:**

During an auction, 2 items will be sold per surviving bot. In the initial auction, 3 items will be sold for each bot. It is up to the bots how they will bid: some bots may spend lots on a cool sword, while others could choose to buy healing in large amounts. There is an auction every few hundred turns. Items start at cost 1.

**Fighting:**

After the auction, your bots will be pitted against each other. With swords to strike nearby enemies, bows to attack distant bots, and shields to defend yourself, what could go wrong? If you find yourself low on health, you can heal (Which takes between 6 and 8 turns).

**Input:**

As input, your function receives an object filled with functions that can be used to control your bot. This object is also at `window.bots["yourbot"].auction` or `window.bots["yourbot"].fight`.

**Object:**

```
//within window.bots["yourbot"]
mode: integer, //0=Dead, 1=Auction, 2=Fight
items: object, //All items owned
coins: integer,
health: integer,
auction: {
    itemlist: array, //Array of item objects
    placeBid(coins), //Bid on item
    incrementBid(amount), //Bids (current + amount)
    item: {
        current: integer, //Current highest bid
        bidder: string, //Current highest bidder
        type: integer, //1=Sword, 2=Bow, 3=Quiver, 4=Shield, 5=Healing
        power: integer, //Item power (Attack amount, healing amount, or block percentage)
        units: integer //Only for healing and quivers; amount of turns taken to heal, or amount of arrows in quiver
    }
},
fight: {
    botList: array, //List of bots
    surrenderTo(bot), //Surrenders to a specific bot
    move: {
        north(), //Y+
        east(), //X+
        south(), //Y-
        west(), //X-
    }
    use: {
        swordAttack(bot OR [x,y]), //Attacks a bot, but only if it is adjacent to attacker
        bow(bot OR [x,y]), //Shoots bow at bot, bot must be within 5 spaces
        shield(), //Raises shield for 5 turns
        heal(sor) //Uses least powerful healing or takes input sort function
    }
    util: {
        getNearest(), //Returns nearest bot
        getBot(name), //Returns a specific bot by name
        atLocation([x,y]), //Returns bot at a certain location
        gridSize(), //Returns the side length of the square arena
        getPosition(), //Returns array [x,y] of caller bot
        see([x,y]), //Returns true or false, depending on if there is a bot in a certain location
    }
}

//within other bot nearestBot(), getBot(), botList, or atLocation(x, y)
location: array, //[x,y]
name: string, //Bot's name
items: object //All objects owned by bot

//within items
type: integer, //1=Sword, 2=Bow, 3=Quiver, 4=Shield, 5=Healing
power: integer, //Item power (Attack amount, healing amount, or block percentage)
units: integer //Only for healing and quivers; amount of turns taken to heal, or amount of arrows in quiver
```

**How it Works:**

You will start in an auction. With your 2000 coins, you can bid on items using the functions `placeBid(price)` or `incrementBid(amount)`. If nobody bids for 5 turns, the item is sold. Once the items are all gone, the fight begins. The initial auction focuses mainly on swords, bows, and shields. During the fight, you can attack players using simple methods like `bow(nearestPlayer())`, or more complex methods involving mapping the area with `see([x,y])` and `atLocation([x,y])`. When the fight round is over, another auction starts, which mainly focuses on healing and quivers. When the fight begins again, you will be able to heal (Make sure you shield right before doing so!). After that fight, another auction will commence. This will repeat until one person remains, or all other bots use `surrenderTo(bot)`. Inflicting damage on another bot gets you 1 coin per point, and you get a 500 coin bonus for killing a bot. If a bot surrenders to you, you earn 100 coins. Store information that you bot may use in `window.bots[yourBotName]`. Note that a copy of this object is passed to your bot, but storing a varibale in this object will only affect it locally. Coordinates range from [0,0] in the corner to [max,max] in the opposite corner, max being `round(22.36 * sqrt(botCount))`.

**Function Specifications:**

```
placeBid(coins)
    Inputs amount of coins to set the bidding at
    If lower than current highest bid or another bid in that turn, returns 1
    If input is invalid, returns 2
    Will set auction.item.current to coins and auction.item.bidder to your bot name
incrementBid(amount)
    Inputs amount of coins to increase bidding by
    Adds to highest bid in last turn
    If lower than current highest bid or another bid in that turn, returns 1
    If input is invalid, returns 2
    Will add amount to auction.item.current and auction.item.bidder to your bot name
moveNorth()
    Will move bot 1 space Y+
    Returns 1 if bot is at far North edge of arena
moveEast()
    Will move bot 1 space X+
    Returns 1 if bot is at far East edge of arena
moveSouth()
    Will move bot 1 space Y-
    Returns 1 if bot is at far South edge of arena
moveWest()
    Will move bot 1 space X-
    Returns 1 if bot is at far West edge of arena
getNearest()
    Returns the nearest bot as of the last turn
    Read information: location, name, items
getBot(name)
    Inputs a string, containing the name of a bot
    If bot does not exist, returns 1
    If bot is dead, returns 2
    If input is invalid, returns 3
    Returns bot as of last turn
atLocation([x,y]) or atLocation(x,y)
    Inputs an array containing coordinates, or two integer coordinates
    Returns bot as of last turn
    If no bot exists in that spot, returns 0
    Invalid input returns 1
gridSize()
    Returns an integer containing the side length of the arena
getPosition()
    Returns an array [x,y] containing the position of the bot
surrenderTo(bot)
    Takes bot as input
    Will set mode to 0 on your bot
    Gives bot surrendered to 100 coins
    Returns 1 if input is invalid
    Returns 2 if bot is dead or inexistant
see([x,y])
    Returns true if bot is in location
    Returns false if input is invalid or no bot exists in location
swordAttack(bot OR [x,y])
    Takes either a bot or [x,y] coordinates as input
    Does as much damage as your best sword
    Will return 1 if input is invalid
    Will return 2 if bot is dead/nonexistant, or if coordinates are out of bounds
    Will return 3 if you don't have a sword
    Will return 4 if bot/coordinates are not within 1 space of your bot
bow(bot OR [x,y])
    Takes either a bot or [x,y] coordinates as input
    Doesas much damage as your best bow
    Will return 1 if input is invalid
    Will return 2 if bot is dead/nonexistant, or if coordinates are out of bounds
    Will return 3 if you don't have a bow, and 5 if you have no arrows
    Will return 4 if bot/coordinates are not within 20 spaces of your bot
shield()
    Blocks as much damage as your best shield as a percentage
    Lasts for 5 turns (Includes turn activated)
    Will return 1 if you don't have a shield
heal()
    Uses your weakest heal, or you can specify a sort function to define the order they are used
    Cannot move for 6-8 turns (Selected randomly)
    Will return 1 if you don't have heal
```

**Item Specifications:**

```
Sword
    The sword is used to attack bots within 1 space
    Has set damage amount (Geometric distribution 10-100)
    Is found in:
        Auction 1 = 35%
        Auction 2 = 30%
        Auction 3 = 15%
        Auction 4 = 5%
Bow
    The bow is used to remotely attack bots within 20 spaces
    Has set damage amount (Geometric distribution 4-40)
    Is found in:
        Auction 1 = 30%
        Auction 2 = 20%
        Auction 3 = 10%
        Auction 4 = 5%
Quiver
    Quivers are purchased with arrows in them, used for shooting bows
    Starts with specific amount of arrows (Geometric distribution 5-20)
    Is found in:
        Auction 1 = 7.5%
        Auction 2 = 10%
        Auction 3 = 25%
        Auction 4 = 40%
        Other auctions = 45%
Shield
    Shields are used to defend against attack
    Starts with a specific block percentage (Geometric distribution 5%-75%)
    Can be used while healing
    Is found in:
        Auction 1 = 20%
        Auction 2 = 30%
        Auction 3 = 20%
        Auction 4 = 10%
Heal
    Heal is used to regenerate during battle
    Heal level is geometric distribution 20-80
    Is found in:
        Auction 1 = 7.5%
        Auction 2 = 10%
        Auction 3 = 30%
        Auction 4 = 40%
        Other auctions = 55%
```

**Example bot:**

```
function readyToFight(obj) {
    var items = obj.items;
    var types = [];
    var coins = obj.coins;
    for (var i = 0, n; i < items.length; i++) {
        n = items[i];
        types.push(n.type);
    }
    if (obj.mode == 1) {
        obj = obj.auction;
        if (obj.item.type == 1) {
            if (types.indexOf(1) != -1) {
                for (var i = 0, n; i < items.length; i++) {
                    n = items[i];
                    if (n.type == 1 && n.power < obj.item.power) {
                        var bid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            } else {
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            }
        } else if (obj.item.type == 2) {
            if (types.indexOf(2) != -1) {
                for (var i = 0, n; i < items.length; i++) {
                    n = items[i];
                    if (n.type == 2 && n.power < obj.item.power) {
                        var bid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            } else {
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            }
        } else if (obj.item.type == 3) {
            if (n.item.price < n.item.units * 2) {
                obj.incrementBid(1);
            }
        } else if (obj.item.type == 4) {
            if (types.indexOf(4) != -1) {
                for (var i = 0, n; i < items.length; i++) {
                    n = items[i];
                    if (n.type == 4 && n.power < obj.item.power) {
                        var bid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            } else {
                if (n.item.price < coins) {
                    obj.incrementBid(1);
                }
            }
        } else if (obj.item.type == 5) {
            if (n.item.price < n.item.power * 5) {
                obj.incrementBid(1);
            }
        }
    } else if (obj.mode == 2) {
        hp = obj.health;
        obj = obj.fight;
        if (types.indexOf(2) != -1) {
            obj.use.bow(obj.nearestPlayer());
        } else if (obj.health < 50 && types.indexOf(5) != -1) {
            obj.use.heal();
        } else {
            //Be scared, or implement better fighting techniques!
        }
    } else {
        //Bot can still see the arena and auction when dead, but cannot fight or bid
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) prohibited, javascript only

Comment: Seems like a solid updated version of the previous idea. I think the "The Challenge" section uses the word "function" too much, and should be updated with slightly less technical language. For example, "Your bot can make one Move action and one Combat action each turn". Additionally, the `fight` object doesn't separate its functions into movement and attacks. I would recommend sub-objects, for example `fight.move.north()` and `fight.attack.sword(x,y)`. And if some of those functions are supposed to be neither movement nor attacks, `fight.util.getNearest()` or the like.

Comment: Okay, got it. Sub objects for `fight`: `move`, `attack`, and `util`

Comment: I did `use` instead of `attack`, so that shields and heal fit under the same category

Comment: Next, only having the option to use the weakest healing item doesn't seem right to me. While non-consumable equipment makes sense to always use the best, and there's only one "trait" so best is never in question, healing would often want to use "largest heal that isn't overheal" or "heal that takes the least time". I suspect it wasn't done that way to simplify the runner, but only allowing smallest heal seems restrictive.

Comment: Perhaps add an optional parameter for a `sort` function? Like `function(a,b){return a.power - b.power}` or `function(a,b){return (a.power / a.units) - (b.power / b.units)}`

Comment: And then the heals are used in the order they are listed

Answer (score 2):

## Operate on a subset of a register

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [quantum-computing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing)

Note: You do **NOT** need to know anything about quantum mechanics or quantum computing to understand this challenge. I've tried to include sufficient background for any old code golfer to realize what's going on.

#### Motivation (much of this can probably be skipped)

In quantum computing, the equivalent of a bit is a **qubit**. Like a bit, a qubit will have a state of OFF or ON (`0` or `1`) when observed, but unlike a bit, a qubit can exist in both states simultaneously while unobserved. Trippy.

What's even trippier is that they don't exist in simple superpositions (40% chance to observe `0`, 60% for `1`)—you can have two qubits that will behave the same when observed, but not when interacting with other qubits. Taking this into account, a convenient representation of a qubit's state is a complex vector, with bases `|0>` and `|1>`. A qubit with state `(1+0i)|0> + (0+0i)|1>` will always show `0` when observed, as will `(0+1i)|0> + (0+0i)|1>` or `(0.6+0.8i)|0> + (0+0i)|1>`. What matters here is the squared magnitude of each component—that's the probability of observing the corresponding basis vector. Noting this, `(-0.5+0.5i)|0> + (-0.5-0.5i)|1>` will "choose" randomly between the two possible states. This ability to have multiple states at once allows qubits to store much, *much* more information than an equal number of bits.

Now, since a qubit is a two-dimensional vector (as far as we're concerned), an operation on a qubit can be represented as a 2x2 matrix. For example, the identity:

```
[[1+0i  0+0i]
 [0+0i  1+0i]]
```

will take any qubit to an equivalent one, while the [Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform), represented by the matrix:

```
[[1+0i  1+0i]
 [1+0i -1+0i]]
```

will turn any pure state (`P(0) == 0 or 1`) into an equal superposition of the two. Check out [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162254/73884) for generation of this matrix, generalized to `n` qubits! These matrices multiply a qubit's vector state to yield a new state.

A qubit on its own is little more useful than a bit. However, they can be put into registers with others, so a "qubyte" can store `0`, `255`, or any arbitrary superposition of the numbers between.

I won't go into depth on entanglement here, but I'll say that it is a property of these qubits that makes storing quantum registers as lists of qubits not work at all (and makes quantum computers outperform classical ones). It works much better to treat a register much like a qubit and give it a vector representation, this time with a basis vector for each observable state. For example, two `(1+0i)|0> + (0+0i)|1>` qubits together form a `(1+0i)|00> + (0+0i)|01> + (0+0i)|10> + (0+0i)|11>` register. Note that the probability distributions of outcomes are identical for the two representations—in this case, both qubits will and up as `0` in both representations.

#### Important stuff again

These registers are nice and all, but it's difficult (and often impossible—try it yourself on `(-0.5+0.5i)|00> + (0+0i)|01> + (0+0i)|10> + (-0.5-0.5i)|11>`!) to extract the state of a single qubit in a register from the register's vector—that is, you can have a register in a state unformable by individual qubits. Fortunately, to apply, say, the Hadamard transform to qubit 2 of a register, we can construct a matrix by which we can multiply the entire register but change only the one qubit. Neat!

Let's say we have an operation `m` on one qubit defined as:

```
[[x y]
 [z w]]
```

and a three-qubit register of qubits `a|0> + b|1>`, `c|0> + d|1>`, and `e|0> + f|1>`. This register has a vector form (treating the first of these qubits as the least significant) of:

`eca|000> + ecb|001> + eda|010> + edb|011> + fca|100> + fcb|101> + fda|110> + fdb|111>`

Defining `g := ax + by` and `h := az + bw`, we see that the result of applying `m` to `a|0> + b|1>` is `g|0> + h|1>`. What we want is a matrix that, when multiplied by the register state above, yields the same but with `a` and `b` replaced by `g` and `h`, respectively:

`ecg|000> + ech|001> + edg|010> + edh|011> + fcg|100> + fch|101> + fdg|110> + fdh|111>`

Let's look at a matrix that does just this:

```
[[x y 0 0 0 0 0 0]     [[eca]     [[ecax + ecby]     [[ecg]
 [z w 0 0 0 0 0 0]      [ecb]      [ecaz + ecbw]      [ech]
 [0 0 x y 0 0 0 0]      [eda]      [edax + edby]      [edg]
 [0 0 z w 0 0 0 0]  \/  [edb]  ——  [edaz + edbw]  ——  [edh]
 [0 0 0 0 x y 0 0]  /\  [fca]  ——  [fcax + fcby]  ——  [fcg]
 [0 0 0 0 z w 0 0]      [fcb]      [fcaz + fcbw]      [fch]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 x y]      [fda]      [fdax + fdby]      [fdg]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 z w]]     [fdb]]     [fdaz + fdbw]]     [fdh]]
```

How nice. Of course, we can operate of qubit 1 or 2 (0-indexed) with a modified version of the very same matrix:

```
[[x 0 y 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 x 0 y 0 0 0 0]
 [z 0 w 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 z 0 w 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 x 0 y 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 x 0 y]
 [0 0 0 0 z 0 w 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 z 0 w]]

[[x 0 0 0 y 0 0 0]
 [0 x 0 0 0 y 0 0]
 [0 0 x 0 0 0 y 0]
 [0 0 0 x 0 0 0 y]
 [z 0 0 0 w 0 0 0]
 [0 z 0 0 0 w 0 0]
 [0 0 z 0 0 0 w 0]
 [0 0 0 z 0 0 0 w]]
```

These are the same as before, but with the 2x2 squares spread out a bit and overlapping. Verification of these matrices is left as an exercise for the reader.

You can also perform multi-qubit operations (like the controlled-NOT gate) on just part of a register in much the same fashion. Performing on qubits 0 and 2 of a 3-qubit register the following operation:

```
[[a b c d]
 [e f g h]
 [i j k l]
 [m n o p]]
```

can be accomplished with yet another 8x8 matrix:

```
[[a b 0 0 c d 0 0]
 [e f 0 0 g h 0 0]
 [0 0 a b 0 0 c d]
 [0 0 e f 0 0 g h]
 [i j 0 0 k l 0 0]
 [m n 0 0 o p 0 0]
 [0 0 i j 0 0 k l]
 [0 0 m n 0 0 o p]]
```

This can be generalized to an operation on `m` qubits of a register of `n` qubits, where `0 ≤ m ≤ n`; in fact, that's what this challenge'll do!

#### Your task (at long last!)

Write a program or function. It must:

- Take as input a nonnegative integer `n`.
- Take as input a list of `m` distinct integers from 0 to `n` (inclusive).
- Take as input a 2<sup>m</sup>x2<sup>m</sup> matrix of integers that represents the operation to be performed on the qubits of an `n`-qubit register indicated (in order) by the aforementioned list.
- Return as output a 2<sup>n</sup>x2<sup>n</sup> matrix of integers that represents an operation on the entire register equivalent to applying the given matrix to the indicated qubits.

#### Test cases

```
n = 4
qubits = {2}
Operation: [[1  2]
            [3  4]]
Return: [[1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]
         [0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0]
         [0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0]
         [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2]
         [3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0]
         [0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0]
         [0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0]
         [0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4]
         [1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]
         [0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0]
         [0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0]
         [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2]
         [3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0]
         [0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0]
         [0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0]
         [0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4]]

n = 3
qubits = {0, 2}
Operation: [[1  2  3  4 ]
            [5  6  7  8 ]
            [9  10 11 12]
            [13 14 15 16]]
Return: [[1  2  0  0  3  4  0  0 ]
         [5  6  0  0  7  8  0  0 ]
         [0  0  1  2  0  0  3  4 ]
         [0  0  5  6  0  0  7  8 ]
         [9  10 0  0  11 12 0  0 ]
         [13 14 0  0  15 16 0  0 ]
         [0  0  9  10 0  0  11 12]
         [0  0  13 14 0  0  15 16]]

n = 3
qubits = {2, 0}
Operation: [[1  2  3  4 ]
            [5  6  7  8 ]
            [9  10 11 12]
            [13 14 15 16]]
Return: [[1  3  0  0  2  4  0  0 ]
         [9  11 0  0  10 12 0  0 ]
         [0  0  1  3  0  0  2  4 ]
         [0  0  9  11 0  0  10 12]
         [5  7  0  0  6  8  0  0 ]
         [13 15 0  0  14 16 0  0 ]
         [0  0  5  7  0  0  6  8 ]
         [0  0  13 15 0  0  14 16]]
Wow, things get weird.

Operation: 2^m x 2^m identity matrix
Return: 2^n x 2^n identity matrix
```

n = 5

qubits = {3, 0, 4, 2, 7}

Operation: [Pastebin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Return: [Pastebin] (TODO)

#### Rules

As usual, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) apply. Builtins are allowed, but try to include a solution *sans* builtin as well.

You can 1-index or reverse the list if desired.

[I/O is flexible.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) in each language wins!

---

> ## Sandboxy stuff
>
> Anything worth mentioning that I missed?
>
> Is there another application of this that might be easier to explain and scare fewer people off?
>
> Thanks!

Comment: If I understood correctly, the part "it's difficult to extract the state of a single qubit in the register from the register's vector." means that most "registers" cannot be formed by (multiple) single qubits, correct?

Comment: @user202729 That is correct.

Comment: Is there a way to rearrange the post so that the task is on top and the explanation comes later?

Answer (score 2):

## Single-Digit Representations of Natural Numbers

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery), [expression-building](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-building), [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Introduction

[Dr. Inder Taneja](https://inderjtaneja.com/) is a Mathematics Professor at the Federal University of Santa Catarina who wrote and published "[Single Digit Representations of Natural Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03501)". In this paper, he describes each natural number from 0 to 1000 in terms of each of the digits 1 through 9 in as few digits as possible and using only the five basic arithmetic operations.

For example, the entry for "282" written only using the digit "3" looks like this:

> 3 + 3 * (3 * (3 ^ 3 + 3) + 3)

Similarly, "466" written using the digit "7" looks like this:

> 7 * 77 + 77 / 7 - 77 - 7

This is also described in the first half of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ruC5A9EzzE) on the Numberphile youtube channel.

This [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge will ask you to write a program (or function, class, etc.) which takes two inputs and outputs a valid mathematical expression according to the rules used by Dr. Taneja. Your score will be calculated based on the size of your code *and* the quality of your outputs.

### Details

Write a program (or function, class, etc.) which takes two integers as input. The first of these will be an integer from 0 to 1000, inclusive. The second number will be a digit from 1 to 9, inclusive.

The program shall output an expression of the first input as a series of arithmetic operations on numbers whose digits are exclusively the digit specified as the second input.

In addition to parentheses `(` and `)`, the following arithmetic operators are allowed in your output:

- addition (represented by the `+`)
- subtraction (represented by the `-`)
- multiplication (represented by the `*`)
- division (represented by the `/`)
- power (represented by the `^`)

Numbers, as stated before, must be composed entirely of the digit specified by the second input, but they can be any number of digits. Numbers can be positive or negative. Number tokens cannot contain any characters besides the digit specified and, if negative, a `-` at the beginning.

Any form and amount of whitespace, including no whitespace at all, is allowed around each token in your output, where "token" refers to a number, operator, or parentheses. Your program's output may not contain any other characters.

The order of operations are evaluated in [the usual manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

### Scoring

Dr. Taneja claims that his answers use "as few digits as possible"; unfortunately, his paper does not show how to prove that a solution is truly minimal. In the spirit of preserving that goal, however, the quality of your solutions will contribute to your score.

The quality of an output is measured, as Dr. Taneja says, by the number of digits used. For example, consider the output for "466" and "7":

> 7 * 77 + 77 / 7 - 77 - 7

This has a score of 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 9. **Smaller is better.**

Your code's score is:

```
score = 2 * <worst_scoring_output> + <solution_bytecount>
```

**The lowest scoring valid solution wins.**

You may determine your worst output either by test battery (trying every input) or logical proof. The following shell script can be used to compute your worst-scoring output, assuming your program is an executable which takes input as command-line arguments and provides output to stdout on a single line. When executing this script, provide the path to your program executable as a command-line argument.

```
// TODO: write a shell script which could compute your bonus score
```

### Rules

Input and output may use [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). This includes writing a function which takes the inputs as arguments to the function and returns or prints a string as described.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the size of your code in bytes forms a significant part of your score. The [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, this includes parsing the original paper to "look up" Dr. Taneja's solution for a combination of inputs.

Reasonable adjustments to the output format are allowed; for instance: if your language has a native `Expression` object for mathematical expressions but its `toString()` (or equivalent) method represents the power operator as two asterisks rather than a caret, you may use the native representation.

Similarly, if it is easier for you to format your output as an equation rather than a one-sided expression, you may do so. For example, you may output `<number> = <expression>` or `<expression> = <number>` rather than simply `<expression>` (where the number is the first input to the program and the expression is the output as defined in the challenge section). Note that in this case, only the digit count of your expressions contribute to your score.

### Example Input and Output

Your outputs may vary, but are still valid provided all explicitly-stated rules are respected.

Input:

> 282 3

Output:

> 3 + 3 * (3 * (3 ^ 3 + 3) + 3)

Input:

> 0 7

Output:

> 7 - 7

Input:

> 1000 9

Output:

> 999 + 9 / 9

Input:

> 466 7

Output:

> 7 * 77 + 77 / 7 - 77 - 7

Comment: Welcome to the site! I suggest including [tag:test-battery] as a winning criterion here—in fact, this is almost exactly the challenge described in the [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/test-battery/info)!

Comment: @Scrooble thank you! do you mean anything besides just tagging it as test-battery? i've added (to the top) a list of the tags i intend to use for this challenge.

Comment: Nope, that's all I meant! You can use `[tag:tag-name]` for the nice-looking tag links.

Comment: Are you allowed to concatenate, i.e. `36 = 3 + 33`? (I vote no, but it's quite common to allow that.)

Comment: @Nathaniel concatenation is not allowed as an operator in the output; however, your output is allowed to have multi-digit numbers as long as all of the digits are the digit specified.

Comment: I'd prefer a version that does not include the bonus. In fact, I think that it should instead be the primary scoring method, e.g. "each submission's score is the total number of digits used across all inputs". Bonus points in Code Golf tend to quickly become either ignored or mandatory

Comment: @KamilDrakari i really like that suggestion. i was worried it would be hard to find a bonus point value that doesn't end up getting ignored because it isn't worth the extra bytes.

Comment: @KamilDrakari what do you think of your score being the score of your program + your bytecount, to preserve the golf aspect?

Comment: If you just score it the way I mentioned, adding up all digits used, then I think the golfing would just be way too inconsequential in comparison. Maybe "highest number of digits + byte count"? It's not that different from the current scoring, but it avoids weird cutoffs and negative points so it's more likely that both parts matter.

Comment: @KamilDrakari i've re-written the scoring rules. please let me know what you think. i think it strikes a nice balance between golfing and quality outputs.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Looks good. I think having that script prepared that will calculate the score is definitely a good idea since manually testing all 9000 input possibilities would be tedious. It would also be nice if that script, in addition to outputting the score (or just "highest_scoring_output" since having it count bytes as well might be problematic), also said which input pair is responsible.

Comment: The problem space of [tag:expression-building] has been fairly well explored, and there are a few questions which this might be considered to duplicate. I personally would vote to close as a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32085/194 : adding exponentiation as a supported operator and a loop to find the smallest `k` are both trivial changes IMO.

Comment: Wait… just how *does* the length of my code affect my score?

Comment: @StephenLeppik your score is: `2 * [worst_scoring_output] + [length_of_code]`. lower score is better. is that not clear?

Answer (score 2):

## The Derby Stakes

The Derby is a horse race run (near) annually since 1780 near the town of Epsom and is the middle leg of the Triple Crown. The race covers one mile, four furlongs, and six yards. Over the years it has had as few as 4 and as many as 34 entries. The fastest winning time was in 2010 at 2m31.33, but I'm old-fashioned and like horse race results only to the nearest fifth of a second. So let's call it 2:31 2/5.

### The task

We will ID horses by number from 0 or 1 (your choice) up to the number of horses in the race (could be anything from 4 to 34).

The task is to take a list of the *average horse speeds in miles per hour* and produce a report of the race. The report has:

1. the winning horse ID and its winning time;
2. the other horse IDs in their order of finish and the difference between each time and the time of the horse that finished ahead of it.

However:

3. the times are to the nearest fifth of a second. There can be ties, *which must be listed in random order*;
4. some horses might not finish the race, in which case their average speed is 0.

### I/O

The input will have between 4 and 34 non-negative numbers (average speeds) rounded to one decimal place, in any convenient format for your language. The horse ID is just the index (starting at 0 or 1) of their average speed.

The output can be any convenient format, as long as the winner is "first" (in the sense of top-most or left-most) and the other horses are listed in a way that makes their finishing order clear.

The times have to be rounded to the nearest fifth of a second, but otherwise can be represented however you like, such as the number of seconds, or some format like `2:31.4` or whatever. If the time is in "seconds flat", as they say, either `2:32.0` or `2:32` (for example) is fine.

For horses that don't finish the race, no time difference really makes sense, so anything that just indicates they didn't finish is fine. But the do have to appear in the report, and if more than one horse does not finish they have to be listed randomly.

The point with the output is that it needs to be *clear*, but the format itself is not so important.

You also need to state in your answer how you have ensured that ties are output in a random order.

### Test case

```
31.8, 0, 32.9, 32.1, 30.8, 31.8, 31.1, 33.1  

8 2:43.6
3 0:01.0
4 0:04.0
1 0:01.6
6 0:00.0
7 0:03.8
5 0.01.8
2 DNF

"I made the ranking of ties random by using `rank(x, ties.method = "random")` in R."
```

I chose a particular time format and used "DNF" for the horse that didn't finish, but you don't need to adhere to these.

I will make more test cases if this challenge seems interesting to anyone.

This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf). Standard loopholes forbidden.

Comment: I assume .5 is expected to be rounded to .6 ?

Comment: Do the times get rounded to 1/5 of a second before calculating the differences, or are the differences rounded to 1/5 of a second?

Comment: Also you might want (or not) to clarify how many miles is 1 mile, 4 furlongs and 6 yards. Or it could be another code-golf challenge if it doesn’t already exist :)

Answer (score 2):

## How far can I throw a ball up the hill?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given an initial velocity, an angle to throw the ball, and the angle of a hill, determine how far the ball will go before it hits the ground due to gravity.

Refer to the image below. V=initial velocity vector, a1=angle of hill, a2=angle ball is thrown at, d=distance ball will travel

### [image: Highly detailed image]

#### Inputs

- The velocity the ball is thrown at (m/s)
- The angle from level ground that the ball is thrown at (radians or degrees)
- The angle from level ground the hill is at

#### Output

- The number of meters the ball travels before hitting the ground

---

### Specifics

- Gravity will pull the ball downwards at 9.81 m/s^2
- Due to floating point rounding, the answer only need be correct within 0.1 of my test case examples
- The input angle can be between 0 and pi/2 radians (or 90 degrees)
- An angle of 0 means the ball is thrown horizontally across the ground, which hits the ground at 0 meters
- An angle of pi/2 radians (or 90 degrees) means the ball is thrown vertically and hits the ground at 0 meters
- The angle of the hill will always be less or equal than the angle the ball is thrown at
- This is code golf, fewest bytes wins

[Related to task 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63014/the-interview-the-front-nine)

---

### Test cases

```
pi/4  (20, 0.7853981633974483, 0) = 40.8
pi/5  (20, 0.6283185307179586, 0) = 38.8
pi/6  (10, 0.5235987755982988, 0) = 8.8
pi/3  (10, 1.0471975511965976, 0) = 8.8
pi/2  (5,  1.5707963267948966, 0) = 0.0
0     (5,  0,                  0) = 0.0
```

---

### Sandbox

I'm not sure what standard rules are used when accounting for floating point errors, is allowing a .1 margin of error fine?

Test cases for angles > 0 to come.

Comment: I think allowing both degrees and radians would be better.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Added a bit more to the challenge.

Comment: I think that in light of the changes, some of the points need to be updated. Point 3 talks about *the* input angle (singular), but may no longer be necessary at all. Point 4 also looks out of date. With respect to floating point errors, that's tricky to do well. IMO the best approach is to specify a range of input values and an error (relative or absolute) which must be obtained within that range; but to verify that the requirements are reasonable may require numerical analysis.

Comment: While this is mathematically interesting, it does not allow for very much solution variation.

Comment: 1. Regarding floating point inaccuracies, you can visit [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/how-should-a-challenge-allow-floating-point-imprecision-to-be-ignored) to get some inspiration and guidance. 2. I think [tag:physics] is a good fit here. 3. In its current form, if posted, the challenge is very likely to be closed as *Unclear what you are asking*, since you don't include a way to compute that distance. I suggest adding this to the challenge

Comment: I don't think such challenges (where there is a formula, and deriving the formula is the main part of the challenge) have many interesting solutions. [Explicit form](https://tio.run/##dZFBS8QwEIXv@RUDgmipdi0IehC77sFr0WUv4kK2jjaQZCBJq7X0t9fJgqXs6m0yvPfNe8TIUKORQVVyHM8SWJExaAOEWnmghgcCbKVuZEDwndmRZqnWHSTngvV9i5oqFbqULY4@l/ZDYwq10no/DnAHfb5IoVTZdQqLIfpEX5NT32SD1JvJ36KLMaZNtP7SgS@tyBfzG8/Kzt6DcKi5R4ubA84ec7C6gOMEyVraYgouhKwq1OiYSZYZt5c3V8CNDWTgt3nsEZTBB3wnh08oq/rRUWPfWPpfkiTP5lAhvkryKo7LsGYWW0@S42CnonTKhgIO5C9/3n8V8V8CUWy9I49gpcF7zjuOPw). (cc @Mr.Xcoder )

Comment: You should make it clear that the output is the **horizontal** length traveled (instead of the arc length)

Comment: @user202729 I *myself* know how to solve the challenge in its current form, however I just pointed out that a larger audience might not receive this too well. Perhaps this challenge isn’t really suited for our format on PPCG. (P.S. the length is not horizontal, it’s along the inclined plane.)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder For the current test cases they're equivalent anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### Queuez

A typical stack-based lanaguage uses nilads, monads, dyads, and occasionally operations with larger numbers of arguments. As each operation is processed, the values are stored on a stack, so that if you want to apply an operation to the result of other operation(s), you simply invoke those operations (and predecessor operations if necessary), at which point their results will end up on the stack ready for the operation you provide next.

Queuez is a fictional language which works differently: instead of the results being stored on a stack, they are stored in a queue, so you have to be careful how you manage your order of operations. For example, let's imagine that digits are nilads and `-` and `/` are dyads and you want to calculate `((a / c) - f) / ((b / d) - e)`. In a stack-based language you would write this as `ac/f-bd/e-/`, however in Queuez you need to write this as `acbd/f/e--/`. Explanation:

```
Command Stack
a       a
c       a c
/       a/c
f       a/c f
-       a/c-f
b       a/c-f b
d       a/c-f b d
/       a/c-f b/d
e       a/c-f b/d e
-       a/c-+f b/d-e
/       (a/c-f)/(b/d-e)
Command Queue
a       a
c       a c
b       a c b
d       a c b d
/       b d a/c
f       b d a/c f
/       a/c f b/d
e       a/c f b/d e
-       b/d e a/c-f
-       a/c-f b/d-e
/       (a/c-f)/(b/d-e)
```

Please write a program or function that converts a program written in a fictional stack-based language into the equivalent Queuez. The actual nilads, monads and dyads of the two lanaguages will be arbitrarily mapped to three sets of at least 10 printable ASCII characters of your choice (you are not required to use letters or mathematical symbols); your answer only has to output the correct rearrangement based on which characters you have chosen to represent nilads, monads and dyads. You can assume that there will be one value left on the stack/queue at the end of the program. Normal [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

If you prefer, you can reverse the dyad argument order, but this must apply both to the original stack-based language and the output. For instance, for the input `edb/-fca/-/` you would need to output `dbcae/f/--/`:

```
Command Stack
e       e
d       d e
b       b d e
/       b/d e
-       b/d-e
f       f b/d-e
c       c f b/d-e
a       a c f b/d-e
/       a/c f b/d-e
-       a/c-f b/d-e
/       (a/c-f)/(b/d-e)
Command Queue
d       d
b       b d
c       c b d
a       a c b d
e       e a c b d
/       b/d e a c
f       f b/d e a c
/       a/c f b/d e
-       b/d-e a/c f
-       a/c-f b/d-e
/       (a/c-f)/(b/d-e)
```

Comment: By "ASCII" did you mean "characters" or "symbols"? (can we use SBCS?)

Comment: I think this needs to be narrowed from "Make up a language with the operators of your choice, and then do the real task on the basis of that language". That has the potential to move the golfing from the program to the definition of the task, e.g. by making all the dyads commute in order to simplify the transformations, or making all the monads no-ops so that they just serve to rearrange the queue, or having some operators which build lists and an eval dyad which evaluates a string over a list in a stack-based way, or ...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry, that was not the intent of the challenge; thank you for pointing out that it needed clarification. Hopefully this new wording will indicate that the meaning of the operators is unknown and therefore the work lies in finding the appropriate rearrangement.

Comment: @user202729 You don't know the underlying SBCS of the language because you don't need to know, all you know is that it has been mapped to three sets of printable ASCII characters of your choice.

Comment: @Neil Then call them "bytes".

Answer (score 2):

## Multidimensional orthodiagonal steps

Step further in step generation.
Navigation in 2d matrix is common, but something uncommon is even more insteresting.
Now I'll ask you to develope shortest solutions to generate all possible steps in N-dimensional matrix.

### Challenge

Your code takes positive integer number N > 0 as input.
Your code must output all possible steps in matrix of N dimensions. In other words, you need to output coordinates of all cells that touch (0;...;0) cell in any way.

### Examples:

Input: 1
Output:

```
(-1)
(1)
```

Input: 2
Output:

```
(0,1)
(0,-1)
(1,0)
(-1,0)
(1,1)
(1,-1)
(-1,1)
(-1,-1)
```

Input 3:
Output:

```
(0,1,0)   (0,1,1)    (0,1,-1)
(0,-1,0)  (0,-1,1)   (0,-1,-1)
(1,0,0)   (1,0,1)    (1,0,-1)
(-1,0,0)  (-1,0,1)   (-1,0,-1)
(1,1,0)   (1,1,1)    (1,1,-1)
(1,-1,0)  (1,-1,1)   (1,-1,-1)
(-1,1,0)  (-1,1,1)   (-1,1,-1)
(-1,-1,0) (-1,-1,1)  (-1,-1,-1)
(0,0,1)
(0,0,-1)
```

### Rules

1. Standart loopholes are disalowed
2. Input number is always integer and always greater than zero
3. Output order is not relevant
4. Output is flexible. Coordinates just need to be distinguishable
5. This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: Some typos: *insteresting* → *interesting*, *develope* → *develop*, *Standart* → *Standard*, *disalowed* → *disallowed*

Answer (score 2):

#### [Fridge magnet substitution (posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164833/fridge-magnet-substitution)

Comment: You should add 6 = 9, 7 = L, and C = U. If you're willing to have nuance like intransitivity and directionality, you could add Z = 2 (but not Z = R) H = I (but not H = 1), 7 = T (But not T = L), P => D (D doesn't really work for P, but P acts like a lower case d if you flip it over), Q => O (sorta works if you flip over Q), T => I (also flipped), V => C/U

Comment: Good additions! I thought of having directionality, but I wanted to keep the commutation that message A->B implies B->A. I'll add the other ones though.

Answer (score 2):

## Treasure Map Drawing Bot

You're organizing a treasure hunt for your friends. To conduct things more easily, you want to draw a map of all locations where you hid the precious objects.

### Input

A string consisting of the locations of the objects separated by newlines. Each location is represented by two non-negative integer coordinates describing the position in the field by an x- and y-coordinate, `0 0` being the upper left corner. Example:

```
1 2
3 0
0 1
```

### Challenge

Your function or program should be able to construct a map denoting every given location with an `x` where the mark is found in row y + 1 and column x + 1 in the output. Unmarked locations are represented with a  . The map also consists of a frame where the corners are `+`s, the vertical lines are `|`s and the horizontal lines are `-`s. Map for the input example given above:

```
+----+
|   x|
|x   |
| x  |
+----+
```

### Possible Test Cases

---

```
"0 0"
=>
+-+
|x|
+-+
```

---

```
"0 10
 5 5
 10 0"
=>
+-----------+
|          x|
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|     x     |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|x          |
+-----------+
```

---

```
""
=>
++
++
```

---

```
"0 0
 0 2
 2 0"
=>
+---+
|x x|
|   |
|x  |
+---+
```

---

Of course, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), meaning that the solution with the lowest byte count wins!

Comment: You may wish to clarify that the (0,0) position is the *upper left corner*. This is common in computer graphics in my experience, but not any other field. If that isn't correct, then your test cases seem to be wrong (and you should clarify where the (0,0) position is anyway).

Comment: Thanks, did that.

Answer (score 2):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [hexagonal-grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

## Formic Functions 2: Hierarchies

---

**[Watch live](http://placeholder) | [Active answers](http://placeholder) | [Add new answer](http://placeholder) | [Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77964/formic-functions-2-hierarchies) | [Source code](http://placeholder) | [Leaderboard](http://placeholder)**

*This is an open-ended challenge. New answers and updates are always welcome.*

We've seen the territorial [highland ants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest) wander the lands in search of food. There have also been talks of aggressive [forest ants](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16415/74965) lurking down below whilst feasting on fungi. These ants, however, are unlike any you've seen before. Collecting food is their goal, as always, but **colonies don't need a queen** - all ants of this subfamily are capable of creating offspring. There's a catch, though. New ants have less strength than their parent, unless the parent ant spends a large amount of food on them. Ants are capable of killing others weaker than them, and weaker ants are worth less, so your ants need to make careful choices.

---

## [Watching the game](http://placeholder)

Because this competition is made in JavaScript, you can see what other players have made already directly in your browser. Just click on one of the links above - you'll figure out the rest.

## [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77964/formic-functions-2-hierarchies)

To keep the comment section clean, I highly encourage you to use the dedicated chat room for questions and discussion.

## [Leaderboard](http://placeholder)

No official tournaments available yet.

## Screenshots

Here are a couple of images taken at the end of a game that should entice you:

No screenshots available yet.

You can look at more simply by running games in your browser. The controller also allows you to zoom in so you can track the ants' decisions that result in the large-scale patterns you ultimately see.

---

## Definitions

A value range is indicated by a number followed by two dots and another number. "0..7" means "between 0 and 7, inclusive". A different type of range is indicated by a number followed by a plus sign. "1024+" means "greater than or equal to 1024".

---

## Programming

Your task is to provide a JavaScript class that implements a `getAction(view)` function and optionally a constructor. All code provided by you will be run under [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

The constructor is called with no arguments. It must take no more than one second to run. It must be side-effect free and must consistently result in an identical object after every run.

The `getAction(view)` function (henceforth known as the ant function) is called like this: `yourConstructedObject.getAction(someViewArray);`. It must also be side-effect free and must consistently return an object, and provide the same output every time if provided the same input.

At the start of every game, your ant function is granted 1 second of reserve time. It is also granted an additional 10 milliseconds of time every time it is called. Time measurement starts right before the function call and ends upon return. That time is then taken away from the reserve time. Your function must not run out of the reserve time.

The constructed object and any temporary data combined must not consume more than 64 MB of memory at any time.

Here's a template for you to fill in:

```js
class Entry { // TODO: Change the "Entry" to whatever you want, preferably your entry name. Remember that this is a JavaScript class name, so you can't use some characters.
  constructor() {
    // TODO: Optionally fill this in.
  }

  getAction(view) {
    // TODO: Fill this in.
  }
}
```

---

## Arena

The arena is a toroidal (edge wrapping) grid of hexagonal cells arranged in a rhombus of side length 1500. Initially, all cells have the color 0 and 0.1% have food placed on them, for a total of 2250 pieces of food. Up to 12 entries are randomly chosen every game and have their corresponding ants (one per entry) spawned in random locations, with no more than one ant occupying any cell. The initial turn order of ants is also randomized.

## Game

The game lasts 32768 turns, which are processed sequentially. Every turn, in an unchanging order, each ant has its corresponding function called with the local state of the arena passed as an argument. *In other words, your ant function is called separately for every ant you control.* The action chosen by the ant function is then taken immediately - other ants see the arena changes even during the same turn.

---

## Ants

#### State

Each ant carries the following properties with them:

- **Position:** Implementation-defined.

  - Ants do not have access to their global position.
- **Tier:** An integer representing the tier of an ant.

  - Equal to 0 for all ants not spawned by other ants.
  - Doesn't change over an ant's lifespan.
  - The lower its tier, the less valuable an ant is.
  - There is no theoretical limit on how high or low tier can be.
- **Age:** An integer representing how old an ant is.

  - Initially 0 for all ants.
  - After every action an ant takes its age goes up by one.
- **Food:** An integer representing the amount of food an ant is carrying.

  - Initially 0 for all ants.
  - An ant may carry an unlimited amount of food.
- **Memory:** An integer in the range 0..15 representing the memory of an ant.

  - Initially equal to 0 for all ants not spawned by other ants.
  - An ant may change it as part of any action.
  - Holds no meaning for the controller.
- **Owner:** Implementation-defined.

  - Allows ants to see whether another one is a friend or not.

#### Sight

Each ant sees 6 cells in its neighborhood, as well as the cell it is currently occupying. Each cell contains the following properties:

- **`color`:** An integer in the range 0..7 representing the current color of a cell.
- **`food`:** A boolean representing whether or not a piece of food is present on a cell.
- **`ant`:** An object if an ant is present on a cell, `undefined` otherwise. If present, the object has the following properties:

  - **`tier`:** Maps to **Tier**.
  - **`age`:** An integer in the range 0..3 representing an ant's age on a logarithmic scale. 0 actual age maps to 0, 1..31 actual age maps to 1, 32..1023 actual age maps to 2 and 1024+ maps to 4. **[Sandbox note: I'm torn about whether or not the ants should have access to this information.]**
  - **[Sandbox] Alternative for or complement to `age`: `older`:** A boolean representing whether or not an ant's age is higher that of the currently active ant.
  - **`food`:** An integer in the range 0..3 representing the amount of stored food by an ant on a logarithmic scale. 0 actual food maps to 0, 1..3 actual food maps to 1, 4..15 actual food maps to 2 and 16+ actual food maps to 3.
  - **`memory`:** Maps to **Memory**.
  - **`friend`:** A boolean representing whether or not an ant is under control of the same entry as the currently active ant.

Every turn sight is passed to your ant function as an array of 7 objects, arranged in this order:

```
 0 1
5 6 2
 4 3
```

The view is randomly rotated by a multiple of 60 degrees every time your ant function is called. This means that it's impossible to extract a consistent sense of direction without clever use of the environment.

Accessing one's own state is done by retrieving the ant object of the 7<sup>th</sup> element of the array, like this: `const me = view[6].ant;`

#### Actions

Each ant must perform an action every turn. The possible actions are as follows:

- **Move:** Move to the desired cell.

  - Format: `{cell: 0..6, action: 0}`
  - When moving onto a cell with food on it, an ant automatically picks up the piece of food present.
  - When moving onto a cell with an ant on it, of the two ants only one remains. If the still ant's `tier` value is lower than that of the moving ant, then the still ant dies and is permanently removed from the game. Otherwise, the unfortunate fate awaits the moving ant instead. In either case, the remaining ant gains all the food of the ant that died and one more.
  - Staying still is a valid action and may hold merit in certain situations.
- **Paint:** Change the color of the desired cell to the desired color.

  - Format: `{cell: 0..6, action: 1, color: 0..7}`
  - Changing the color of a cell to the same one is a valid action.
- **Place food:** Put a piece of food onto the desired cell.

  - Format: `{cell: 0..6, action: 2}`
  - Placing a piece of food onto a cell with an ant on it results in that ant immediately picking it up.
  - Placing food costs food. An ant may only place a piece of food if it has at least one food stored, and one food is taken away from it.
  - Placing food onto own cell is a valid action, but placing food onto a cell with a piece of food already on it is *not*.
- **Spawn:** Create a new ant under control of the same entry on the desired cell.

  - Format: `{cell: 0..6, action: 3, tier: -1..+1, state: 0..15}`
  - A parent ant must choose to spend 1, 4 or 16 food on the new ant by specifying a `tier` equal to -1, 0 or +1 respectively.
  - A parent ant may only spawn an ant of the desired tier if it has the necessary amount of food to do so, and that amount is taken away from it.
  - Spawning results in an ant of a tier equal to that of its parent plus the `tier` value specified.
  - A parent ant must choose the initial memory of the new ant by specifying a `state`. **[Sandbox note: I'm considering not letting parents set the initial memory of offspring.]**
  - The new ant is inserted into the turn order right before its parent.
  - Spawning an ant counts as movement for the new ant, and is resolved as such.
  - Spawning an ant onto own cell is a valid action and may hold merit in certain situations.
- **Memorize:** Replace the currently active ant's memory with the desired number.

  - Format: `{memory: 0..15}`
  - Memorization is not an action itself. It must be appended to one of the four previously mentioned actions.
  - An ant may choose to leave this field undefined. No memory change occurs then. **[Sandbox note: Torn about this as well.]**

Format refers to the JavaScript object that must be returned by your ant function to perform a specific action.

Example outputs:

- `{cell: 0, action: 0} // Move to cell 0.`
- `{cell: 6, action: 0} // Do nothing.`
- `{cell: 6, action: 1, color: 0} // Set own cell color to 0.`
- `{cell: 3, action: 2} // Put a piece of food onto cell 3. Invalid if there is a piece of food on cell 3.`
- `{cell: 2, action: 3, tier: -1, state: 3} // Spawn an ant 1 tier lower than that of your own with initial memory equal to 3 on cell 2 at the cost of 1 food. Invalid if you have no food.`
- `{cell: 5, action: 3, tier: +1, state: 11, memory: 14} // Spawn an ant 1 tier higher than that of your own with initial memory equal to 11 on cell 5 at the cost of 16 food whilst committing 14 to memory. Invalid if you have less than 16 food.`
- `{cell: 6, action: 3, tier: 0, state: 0} // Spawn an ant with tier equal to that of your own with initial memory equal to 0 on your own cell at the cost of 4 food. A conflict occurs and the newly spawned ant dies, giving you a piece of food. Effectively, ou lost 3 pieces of food. Invalid if you have less than 4 food.`
- `{cell: 6, action: 3, tier: +1, state: 0} // Spawn an ant 1 tier higher than that of your own with initial memory equal to 0 on your own cell at the cost of 16 food. A conflict occurs and you die, giving the newly spawned ant a piece of food (and any additional food you might've had). Effectively, you upgraded yourself at the cost of 15 food. Invalid if you have less than 16 food.`
- `{cell: 3, action: 0, color: 5, test: true, memory: 1} // Move to cell 3 whilst committing 1 to memory. Values of`color`and`test`are irrelevant. You may choose to include unrelated properties - they are simply ignored.` **[Sandbox note: Maybe the controller shouldn't allow `color` in this case? This looks like it might be a good breeding ground for hard-to-detect bugs.]**

Example invalid outputs *(not exhaustive)*:

- `{cell: 7, action: 0} // Error: Value of "cell" outside required range 0..6.`
- `{cell: 3} // Error: "action" left undefined.`
- `{action: 1, color: 4} // Error: "cell" left undefined.`
- `{cell: 4, action: 3, tier: -1} // Error: "state" left undefined.`

---

## Scoring

At the end of each game, every entry participating in that game is evaluated according to this formula:

[image: formula]

n is the number of ants belonging to the entry currently being evaluated
T<sub>i</sub> is the tier of the i<sup>th</sup> ant belonging to the entry currently being evaluated
F<sub>i</sub> is the amount of food the i<sup>th</sup> ant belonging to the entry currently being evaluated is holding

Or as pseudocode:

```
var evaluation = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < entry.ants.count; i++) {
  var ant = entry.ants[i];
  evaluation += Math.Pow(2, ant.tier) + Math.Pow(2, ant.tier - 1) * ant.food;
}
```

**[Sandbox note: Should I count food as score or not?]**

The final score of each entry is equal to the amount of entries whose evaluation was lower than that of the currently considered entry. This means that the highest score an entry can get is 11.

## Tournaments

A tournament is nothing more than a series of individual games. At any point of a tournament the score of each entry is equal to the average of all of its scores.

#### Official tournaments

Official tournaments will be run by me on the latest version of Chrome on my personal computer, which at the time of writing is an AMD FX-8350, every time a new entry is posted or an existing one receives a meaningful edit. The leaderboard will be updated once the 1<sup>st</sup> place becomes consistent between 6 subsets of played games (which gives a probability of 96.875% that the first place won't change).

As stated before, there is no permanent winner. This means that no checkmark will be awarded to any answer, ever. I will continue to run new tournaments for as long as is practical.

---

## Submissions

Each submission must follow this general format:

---

## *Entry Title*

*[Optional text and pictures]*

*`Code block with your JavaScript class`*

*[Optional text, pictures and code blocks]*

---

Not adhering to the above format may result in the submission not being properly picked up by the controller.

Explanations and pictures are highly encouraged, though not necessary. Making your entry pretty and well-documented will entice me (and probably a lot of people) to upvote it.

## Disqualification

Your entry will be disqualified if it is found to not adhere to the specification correctly. Most of the time problems will be caught by the controller and reported, but some rules can't be checked programmatically, so they'll be enforced by hand. I reserve the right to disqualify an entry manually if it breaks the rules or if I subjectively believe it has not been made with fair competition in mind. I hope I haven't left any loopholes (and therefore won't have to exercise this power), but if I did then this rule prevents them from potentially ruining the entire challenge.

Disqualification during a game results in all of your ants being immediately and permanently removed from the turn order. Disqualification during a tournament invalidates all games in which your entry has participated and terminates the active game (as it would've been invalid anyway). Disqualification during an official tournament, aside from having the effects of a regular tournament disqualification, prohibits your entry from taking part in any future official tournament until meaningfully edited.

This is not supposed to be an additional challenge - helpful error messages along with your ant function's output and the input that disqualified it will be attached to the disqualification notice. I will also paste these messages into a comment informing you of a disqualification should your entry be disqualified during an official tournament.

## Multiple entries and editing

You may provide multiple entries, provided that they do not team up against the others. As long as each entry is working solely towards its own victory, you are permitted to tailor your strategy to take advantage of others' weaknesses. You may also edit your answers whenever you choose. It is up to you whether you post a new entry or edit an existing one; just don't flood the game with nearly identical variations. If you make a variation of another person's entry, remember to give them credit by linking to their entry from your own.

## Example entries

---

## Randant

This entry demonstrates the minimal amount of code needed for something to be considered valid. It returns the same output regardless of input.

```js
class Randant {
  getAction() {
    return {cell: 0, action: 0};
  }
}
```

Because the orientation is random every time, Randant will perform a random walk instead of going straight.

Despite being very simple, this is a perfectly valid submission. It won't ever get disqualified either, because moving is guaranteed to be a valid action.

See Smart Randant on how one could go about improving this entry.

---

## Smart Randant

This entry demonstrates basic mechanics that ought to be commonly used between more advanced entries. It is an improvement of Randant's general design. It depends on input this time around.

```js
class SmartRandant {
  getAction(view) {
    const me = view[6].ant; // Get data about myself

    function wrap(number, cycleLength = 6, negativeSafety = 1) { // Defining functions inside the getAction(view) function is fine
      return (number + cycleLength * negativeSafety) % cycleLength; // Wraps numbers (allows for cyclic array access)
    }

    function stronger(a, b) { // Checks if ant a is stronger than ant b
      return a && (!b || a.tier > b.tier);
    }

    view.forEach((cell, i) => { // Modifying the view is perfectly acceptable (here we do it to store the index alongside each cell)
      cell.index = i;
    });

    const dirs = view.slice(0, 6);
    const safe = dirs.filter((cell, i) => !stronger(dirs[cycle(i - 1)].ant, me) && !stronger(dirs[cycle(i + 1)].ant, me) && stronger(me, cell.ant)); // Create an array of cells that are safe to move to
    // TODO: Also consider attacking other ants that are at the same strength level as us by spawning a stronger ant on their face

    if (safe.length) { // If we've got some safe spaces to move to...
      const victims = safe.filter((cell) => cell.ant && stronger(me, cell.ant)); // Prioritize killing other ants

      if (victims.length) { // If we've got someone to kill...
        const target = victims.reduce((prev, next) => stronger(next.ant, prev.ant) ? next : prev); // Find the strongest victim and target it

        return {cell: target.index, action: 0};
      }

      const food = safe.filter((cell) => cell.food); // Otherwise prioritize grabbing food

      if (food.length) { // If we've got some food to grab...
        return {cell: food[0].index, action: 0} // Just grab any piece
        // TODO: Grab the piece that has the most pieces of food next to it
      }

      return {cell: safe[0].index, action: 0} // Otherwise move to any safe cell
    }

    return {cell: 6, action: 0}; // If we don't have a safe cell to move to, just stay still and hope for the best
    // TODO: Handle this situation better
  }
}
```

As you can see, Smart Randant is a lot smarter than his counterpart. Smart Randant dropped his suicidal tendencies by finding safe cells before moving. Note that despite not being suicidal, he may still be killed by particularly cunning entries. He's also more aggressive - he'll gladly attack opponents weaker than him and will grab nearby food. Finally, if he's got anywhere to go, he will go there. Otherwise, he'll just stay still, hoping for the best.

You may have also noticed that Smart Randant still has a lot to learn. You can edit your entries to your heart's content, so W.I.P. submissions are allowed, or even encouraged.

---

## Straighter

This entry demonstrates smart usage of the environment for the purpose of fighting randomness. It travels in a straight line, leaving behind a path. It also utilizes and expands Smart Randant's basic framework.

[Placeholder]

---

## Meta

The [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77964/formic-functions-2-hierarchies) is active already and is a better place for extended discussion than the comment section. I'd also love to dicuss some preliminary ideas for potential strategies to be used in future entries (though let's try to restrict this dicussion to nothing more than interesting isolated systems rather than full submissions - I'm not particularly interested in posting a nearly-solved challenge).

Most links are broken for now. The controller, for example, doesn't exist yet.

I'm aware that I'll have to make (or find) a custom number library that can handle nearly arbitrarily small and large powers of 2 for scoring (I've managed to design a system which spawns progressively less valuable ants every 2 turns at no cost, leading to a score equal to about `1 + 2e-16384`).

Answer (score 2):

## Is it a table?

#### Challenge

Take an bitmap (in .bmp, 2D array, string containing line break, etc.), check whether it's a table, i.e. the outer border is a rectangle, and each separated (edge-connected) empty part in it is a rectangle.

Equivalently, each space area, including the outside one, has exactly 4 edges.

You can't assume there is or is no space outside of the table.

#### Test cases

**True samples:**

```
############# 
#           #
#           #
#############
#     #     #
#     #     #
#############
```

```
###########
#         #
#         #
#         #
###########
#   #     #
#####     #
# # #######
# # #     #
###########
```

```
###########
###########
##   #   ##
##   #   ##
##### #####
######   ##
######   ##
###########
```

Note that in this test case the smallest space area (with 1 space) is a rectangle, although it doesn't have a rectangular border with `#`.

**False Samples:**

```
###########
#     #   #
#     #   #
#     #####
#         #
###########
```

In this test case the lower-left empty region is a concave hexagon.

```
###########
#    #     #
#    #     #
############
```

The outer border is not a rectangle.

```
############
#          #
#          #
#   ####   #
#   #  #   #
#   ####   #
#          #
############
```

The outer empty region has a "hole" inside.

#### Winning criteria

Shortest code win.

Comment: This is massively unspecified, and based on the test cases I'm not even sure why the truthy cases are tables and some of the falsey cases not.. As stated in the Sandbox description: "_Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it._", which this clearly isn't.. I'm assuming you just had this challenge as a idea and don't have the time yet to fully specify it, in which case it would be better to save it in a local Notepad doc until you have time to specify it, before posting it here. I do the same pretty often.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `the whole one is a rectangle, and each separated part is a rectangle`

Comment: Why is the third test cases truthy? Do we look at the `#` for the outer rectangle, but the spaces for the inner ones? If either both `#` this third truthy case would be false; and if both space (somewhat), I could imagine the second falsey case to be true.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Also Notepad doesn't help wording, so your suggestion is bad

Comment: I meant creating the answer with correct formatting here, then save it in Notepad++ until it's fully specified (which is what I do). Alternatively you can keep it open in your browser tab until it's fully specified before clicking the "post"-button. Either way, it clearly isn't "_Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it._" right now.. That's all I wanted to state. It does look like an interesting challenge when it is fully specified, though. So you'll have my future upvote when it is.

Comment: I think you should prove clearly how [it clearly isn't "Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it."] @KevinCruijssen

Comment: I don't understand this. Why is the third truthy test case truthy? Why are the first and third falsey test cases falsey?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork its outer border is a 8*11 rect, and there are 4 empty rect parts in it, 3 2*3 and a 1*1. First false test contain an empty part with 6 edges, 3rd one with 8 edges

Comment: So [this](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/XwENcAGxsrIyjKWgDBXggklygdD//wA) is also a truthy example?

Comment: @user202729 True. Another true case I think maybe necessary is `###` (no space area)?

Answer (score 2):

> ## *Hexarun!* [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [work-in-progress](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-in-progress)
>
> Hexarun (stylized as *Hexarun!*) is a simultaneous game with complete
>   information.  Hexarun is intended for a minimum of three (3) players.

## Overview

Up to twelve (12) players start on a **regular hexagonal toroidal board** with a number placed on each hexagon.  The objective of the game is to collect the numbers by navigating the board.  Players have complete knowledge of the board and the participating players.  The number on a hexagon is reduced by the amount being collected.  The game ends when all hexagons **become zero** or if the game becomes **stale**.  The player whose collection has the highest sum wins the game.

Each game consists of multiple turns.  Before the first turn, players choose their own starting location.  During each turn, players **move within their vicinity** at the same time.  If a player is alone in a numbered hexagon, this player **collects** the entire number.  If multiple players move into a single hexagon simultaneously, they **split** the number.  Numbers are not exchanged between players during each game.

## Game specifications

1. **Regular hexagonal toroidal board:** Each edge of the board measures `N=2*P` hexagons where `P` is the number of players on the board.  The numbers on the board are placed in concentric rings.  The numbers on the edge of the board are 1, and each successive inner ring follows off the OEIS sequence [A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024) which starts with 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4.  As a final touch, increase the number in the center by 1 if it is not unique on the board.  [[Example Board (N=6)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cBLi.png)
2. A game ends when...

   a. **Hexagons become zero**: Numbers on all hexagons are zero.

   b. **Game becomes stale**: Scores do not change during `6*P` consecutive turns.
3. Legal moves...

   a. ***Run!***: Moves into one of the six (6) neighboring hexagons.

   b. **Nothing**: Does literally nothing.
4. Number collection:

   a. **Collect**: At the end of a turn, a player alone on a hexagon scores `s=h` points, where `h` is the number on the hexagon at the beginning of the turn.

   b. **Split**: At the end of a turn, `n>1` players standing on a hexagon scores `s=h/n` points, where `h` is the number on the hexagon at the beginning of the turn, and `/` is integer division.  The number on the hexagon at the end of the turn becomes `h-s*n`, a.k.a. the remainder.

   *Example: At the end of a turn, a total of 3 players are on a hexagon with number 10, then each gets 3 points and the hexagon becomes 1.*

## How to play

*TODO*

## Tournament rules

*TODO*

## Leaderboard

Comment: Note to self: Implement using [davidje13/koth-webplayer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13891/what-javascript-only-koth-challenges-have-there-been).

Comment: 2*P scaling means that if there are more players, there's more proportional space for each player.  In other words, there's more and more empty space between players.  (As an extreme example, if you have 2 players, each player will have 8 squares each.  If you have 100 players, each player will have 1600 squares each)

Comment: The center of the board is more valuable, but because you are using that OEIS sequence, with big boards, there are tons of squares in the middle that will have the same number.  I think you were aiming to have fights for the middle, but how I see it, there's plenty for everybody.

Comment: Finally, winning this game is primarily done by predicting where people are going to go.  This is problematic, because as it stands, the way to win is to identify bots based on movement, which leads to one-upping.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I meant to say that P is the number of players on the board.  If up to 12 players play at the same time, the edge size is up to 24.  I'm still not entirely sure about that sequence, and it'll take some testplay to see.

Comment: Right.  If you have 12 players, then the edge size is 24.  24*24 = 576, which is 48 squares per player.  With 100 players, it is 200*200 = 40000, which is 400 squares per player.  What you really want is X*sqrt(P), where X is the number of squares per player.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I'm trying to think in your way.  The total number of squares for the hex follows [A003215](https://oeis.org/A003215).  For edge size 24 (number of hexagons on a side of the hexagonal board), there are 24^3-(23)^3=1657 hexagons, so that's approximately 69 hexagons per player.

Comment: 69 is miscalculated, 138 should be the answer.  138 hexagons should be plenty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78279/discussion-between-nathan-merrill-and-frenzy-li).

Answer (score 2):

## Base 18 & Decimal traffic light

Given a number `n<180`, output the `n/10` part and the `n%10` part in 7-seg.

7-seg shapes:

```
 000         222   333         555   666   777   888   999   AAA         CCC         EEE   FFF   GGG
0   0     1     2     3 4   4 5     6         7 8   8 9   9 A   A B     C         D E     F     G     H   H
0   0     1     2     3 4   4 5     6         7 8   8 9   9 A   A B     C         D E     F     G     H   H
0   0     1     2     3 4   4 5     6         7 8   8 9   9 A   A B     C         D E     F     G     H   H
             222   333   444   555   666         888   999   AAA   BBB         DDD   EEE   FFF         HHH
0   0     1 2         3     4     5 6   6     7 8   8     9 A   A B   B C     D   D E     F     G   G H   H
0   0     1 2         3     4     5 6   6     7 8   8     9 A   A B   B C     D   D E     F     G   G H   H
0   0     1 2         3     4     5 6   6     7 8   8     9 A   A B   B C     D   D E     F     G   G H   H
 000         222   333         555   666         888   999         BBB   CCC   DDD   EEE         GGG
```

- Either led on or (led off&background) should be constant, and the left characters mean the other state, or
- At least two of your background, led on and led off should be constant, and the left characters mean the left state.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Comment: add the tag [tag:ascii-art]

Comment: 1. [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54008/194), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9266/194), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2651/194), and plenty more. I wouldn't be surprised if this were closed as a dupe. 2. What does this have to do with traffic lights or base 18? 3. I don't understand the last two bullet points. Are they saying that I can choose to use the same character for on and off and essentially just always output 88? 4. Why is the shape for 0 the same as the shape for 8?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. There are lots of related, but none of these are 2. http://video.baomihua.com/v/18443141 , base 18 because the next letter "i" can be mistaken with "1" 3. clarified somehow, though I don't know which choice you use 4. fixed

Answer (score 2):

## Syllabification and classification (Venpa)

#### Introduction

[Venpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venpa) is a form of classical Tamil poetry, based upon certain rules of metric prosody. The complete rules form a context-free grammar, the task here is to test for a tiny subset of those rules.

#### Letters

- Vowels: a, A, i, I, u, U, e, E, y, Y, o, O, W

  - small case represents "short" vowels, CAPS represent "long" vowels
  - `y` represents the y sound in "my".
  - `W` represents the "ou" sound in "mouse", and always comes in capital (long) form.
- Consonant: everything else

  - the consonants can be in small case or capitals, whichever is convenient.

#### Word Segmenting

Words in the input are seen as composed of segments (which roughly correspond to the usual notion of a syllable). A segment divide occurs where:

- two or more consonants occur together, `tr`, `rpp`, etc.
- a long (capital) vowel occurs in the word, `pO`, `W`, `mY` etc.
- two vowels have occurred since the last segment's end (or the word's beginning).

`sanjIvi` has segments `san`, `jI`, `vi`.
`Yvar` has `Y`,`var`.
`vigadakavi` has `viga`,`daka`,`vi`.
`vAnily` has `vA`,`nily`.
`padAgytAngiha` has `padA`, `gytAn`, `giha`
`radagajaturagapadAdi` has `rada`, `gaja`, `tura`, `gapa`, `dA`, `di`

(Consonants at the end of segments make no difference after segmentation and can be ignored - `gytAn`=`gytA`, `var`=`va`.)

As you can see, the segments are of two types:

1. those with a single vowel, `san`, `Y`, `vA`, called a straight (S) segment
2. those with two vowels, `viga`, `nily`, `padA` called a sequence (Q) segment

So the segment patterns of the above words are:

```
  sanjIvi              =              san + jI + vi          = SSS
  Yvar                 =                 Y + var             = SS
  vigadakavi           =            viga + daka + vi         = QQS
  vAnily               =                vA + nily            = SQ
  padAgytAngiha        =           padA + gytAn + giha       = QQQ
  radagajaturagapadAdi = rada + gaja + tura + gapa + dA + di = QQQQSS
```

#### Permitted patterns

The rules for words allowed in a Venpa are:

1. a word should have one to three segments
2. a one or two segment word can have any pattern (S, Q, SQ, SS, QS, QQ)
3. a three segment word must end in a straight (S) segment

So out of the above, SSS, SS, QQS, and SQ are allowed, QQQ and QQQQSS are not.

#### Task

Given an input word in the above letters, output its segment pattern if it's an allowed word, 
or a false-y value if it's not an allowed word.

#### Input

- Will be a single word composed of the characters mentioned under the Letters heading above

  - (Small case `w` will *not* be present anywhere in the text (neither as a vowel nor as a consonant))

#### Output

- The segment pattern of the input word, if it's an allowed word

  - can use any two distinct unambiguous characters to represent S segments and Q segments
- A false-y value in your language if it's not an allowed word
- Output is undefined for invalid input (i.e. has characters other than those specified)

#### Test cases

```
vigadakavi 
=> QQS
Yvar 
=> SS
padAgytAngiha
=> falsey (QQQ not allowed)
vAnily
=> SQ
katradanA
=> SQS
radagajaturagapadAdi 
=> falsey (more than 3 segments)
TuppArkkuT
=> SSS
mazai
=> Q
```

Comment: fascinating. im probably very unusual, but i would like it even better if it was actual poetry instead of 'p' everywhere, maybe even in tamil script (although that would probably disqualify some languages)

Comment: Yeah, I intended to just remove some extraneous complexity, but somehow having input in this form makes it slightly less interesting even to me (and I'm not sure it removes a meaningful level of complexity anyway, relative to the rest of the task). I'll change it to use the actual consonants if anyone else here also feels this way. (The last two test case inputs are from actual poetry by the way, just with the consonants replaced.)

Comment: Using Tamil script would also be great, but my concern with that is mainly that it might make testing and debugging much harder for people who can't read the script. I can mitigate some of that by providing exhaustive test cases, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: yeah i think i might be a little unusual in my tastes, i still like the puzzle...

Comment: @donbright I've updated the post to use different consonants (corresponding to actual words). I like this version a lot better, but let's see how it's received.

Comment: I wrote a program that solves the examples you gave. my first pass was 60 lines of Rust code. i think it is a really good puzzle, great balance between an interesting puzzle and many ways to possibly reduce code size. very interesting.

Comment: i would like some more examples though. feel like my program might be wrong on some inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## Progrqmming Puzzle andf Co9de Golf |

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)

### Intro

We all make mistakes. You, me, everyone. But not computers. They aren't making any mistake. Not even a single typo.
Time to change this injustice.

### Task

Your task will be to take a string as input, and display the string character by character, and with a cursor, as if someone was typing it. *But there is a twist* : sometimes, the "entered" character will be wrong. In that case there is a little pause, then the last entered character (which is supposed to be wrong) is deleted.

### Rules

- Input and output will contain only printable ASCII characters.
- The cursor should be displayed as `|`, preceded by a space. This will always be displayed, from the empty string to the exact input displayed.
- Each "iteration" (new character) is separated by a 0.25s pause (It takes time to write right). You can have a marge error of 0.05s, meaning the pause have to be lower than 0.2s, and lower than 0.3
- Each character has exactly 1/10 chance to be wrong (that means it will be anything but the right character). In that case you should add a 1s pause ("Wait, did l really made a mistake?"), then delete this character, add a 0.25s pause (with a marge error of 0.05s), then continue.

## Example

### input

`Hello!`

### Possible output

*Note : I am planning to add a gif to show what the code should do. For now, consider every line as a gif frame*

```
H |          // 0.25s pause
He |         // 0.25s   "
Hel |        // 0.25s   "
HelG |       // 1s      "
Hel |        // 0.25s   "
Hell |       // 0.25s   "
Hello |      // 0.25s   "
Hello! |     // done
```

## Note for sandbox

- Is this challenge good enough ?
- Is this challenge already exist ?
- Is this challenge clear enough ?

Comment: Are those typos in the body also intentional? e.g. *whitch*

Comment: @wastl Except for the title, this is just me being bad at writing english

Comment: @AdmBorkBork the wrong character can be anything, except for the character it should have be. In my example the wrong character is a `G`, it could have been a `a`, a `7`, a `#`, but not a `l` since it is the correct character.

Comment: Is it acceptable if the "wrong" character is not random? For example, if a typo on `a` always becomes `b`. It might also be a good idea to restrict what characters need to be handled, e.g. "Input will, and output must, consist of only printable ASCII characters"

Comment: @KamilDrakari as long as the "wrong" character is actually wrong, it's ok. And good idea for the input/output restrictions.

Comment: Can we use `\b` to remove the previous character? How accurate does the delay have to be (0.24 seconds instead of 0.25?). Same question with randomness. Can we have an initial delay before output? Enough is spelt with a `g`.

Comment: @JoKing as long as the output shows that the character is removed, you can use `\b`. i'd say delay will have an error margin of 0.05s (basically 0.2s<delay<0.3s). However the randomness has to be exactly 1/10. I'll edit the question to add those criterias later.

Comment: You say each character has a 1/10 chance of being wrong?  Does this mean answers have to behave non-deterministically, or could a deterministic method be used as long as 1 out of every 10 characters is wrong.

Comment: @CatWizard Answer have to behave non deterministically : the total number of wrong characters will only rely to randomness.

Comment: how are you going to measure exact timing on people's solutions?

Comment: @donbright with a chronometer ? More seriously, the point here is to get aproximately 4 characters in a second (unless there is a wrong one)

Comment: i dont know how you can measure it, since computers run at different speeds, and OSes are not realtime OSes. but i like it enough anyways.

Answer (score 2):

## Convincingly Fake Compression of Random Data [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

As you may know, it is impossible to write an compression method that takes strings of length \$n\$ and returns strings of length \$n - 1\$. This can be proven by a simple argument: Each compression function must be a bijection, because otherwise the compressed strings can not unambiguously be uncompressed. However, just considering bit strings, there are \$2^n\$ strings of length \$n\$, but only \$2^{n-1}\$ strings of length \$n-1\$, thus no such bijection can exist.

In other words, for each attempt to write such a compression function, there exist strings which cannot be compressed.

The task for the cops in this challenge is to write a function which looks like it can compress arbitrary fixed-length strings, and the task of the robbers is to find a string for which the compression function fails.

---

#### Sandbox

I'm not yet convinced if this will actually work as a challenge, mainly if it is feasible for the cops to write a submission which is not easily crackable. It might be easier for large \$n\$ so robbers can not brute force, so I could make the cops winning criterion about getting the safe submission with the lowest \$n\$. Any ideas for a better winning criterion?

Also do you think this will work as a challenge?

Comment: Might be too easy for a challenge. There's a 50% probability that you find a string which fails.

Comment: Looks feasible to me. It may be good to fix the input into binary string, lower-case alphabet, or just ASCII and require the robbers to find two strings that "compress" to the same object.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yes, but with a well-crafted cop submission, it would be difficult to know that a string wasn't "compressed" unless the robber finds two strings that end up with the same string or writes a "decompression" function.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Just run it and measure its length?

Comment: Anyway I think this is only feasible if the cops solution takes a very long time to run even for a single input, for most/all of the counterexamples.

Comment: @user202729 What I meant to say is that it is possible that there exists a "compressed" string that corresponds to only one "uncompressed" string, so it would be "compressed" when you feed it to the cop program. With a good cop program, it may be hard for robbers to find specific examples of strings that have the same "compressed" variation.

Comment: @JungHw Pick random strings of length n and compress it, the expected number of runs until you crack the solution is 2.

Comment: @user202729 That doesn't make sense. Assuming that we use binary strings and exactly two strings compress to one string, the probability of getting no collision after picking 3 strings is `1 * (2^n - 2)/(2^n - 1) * (2^n - 4)/(2^n - 2)`, which should be close to `1` with large enough `n`.

Comment: Perhaps the word "fail" has to be clearer. The challenge sounds possible if "failing" means "producing colliding outputs" instead of something on the lines of "crashing." With binary strings, Mathematica tells me that the expected value of trials needed to find colliding strings is ~946 with length 10, and ~1.05e+6 with length 20.

Comment: @JungHwanMin  Shouldn't generating a random string, compressing it, decompressing the result and checking whether this equals the original string yield a collision with probability 0.5?

Comment: @Laikoni then the robber would need to create a decompression function. Maybe I misunderstood the challenge, but I thought the only requirement for the cop was to include a compression algorithm. Having some obscure compression function that make "decompression" very challenging would make this challenge feasible.

Comment: I suggest changing the challenge specification to my misinterpretation of the challenge specs. ;-) The robber would need to come up with either a decompression function or a counterexample to the compression algorithm (i.e. prove that the compression is not bijective).

Comment: @JungHwanMin Thanks for the suggestions! The problem with the cop providing only a compression function is that they could submit any hash function, because that's what those fake compression functions actually are, and trying to prevent cops from submitting known-to-be-collision-resistant hash functions probably brings us into dupe-distance to [this cnr challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51068/56433).

Comment: So the cops must write a decompression function too?

Comment: @user202729 That's what I originally envisioned, but at the moment that's up for debate in order to make the challenge feasible for the cops.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Now that I think of it again, technically, *every* string fails, because every string has compresses to what at least one other string does too.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Not necessarily. For instance. `{"00" -> "0", "01" -> "1", "10" -> "1", "11" -> "1"}` (i.e. `or` operation). But still, the robber should need to *prove* that a compression fails by providing a pseudo-decompression function and/or providing a counterexample pair.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Japt Shortcuts

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[japt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japt)

[Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) is the PPCG [Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16592/71434) for July, and I'm excited to try it out! In accordance with the [Tips post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121378/71434) I should use the Unicode Shortcuts. However, my keyboard seems to be lacking those important characters like "upside-down exclamation point" needed for optimum golfiness. Please write me a program to change horrible, verbose monstrosities like `â m@VgUb==X` into pristine, optimal code like `â £VgUb¥X`!

### Challenge

Given Japt code as input, output the same code making maximal use of the Unicode Shortcuts Japt supports.

### Rules

- Answers must support inputs containing any combination of valid Japt characters [Sandbox: is there a list of these? In particular, many languages need to use the NULL byte to indicate end of input, does Japt support NULL bytes in the middle of code?].
- Input may be in any reasonable format (string, list of chars, etc.)
- Output may be in any reasonable format, and does not need to be the *same* as the one used as input (e.g. "input as string => output as list of chars" is fine)
- If multiple shortcuts are possible, use the one that replaces the most characters. For example, `===` should be replaced by `¶` not `¥=`.
- Your code does not need to handle ambiguous situations. For example, `====` could be shortened to `¶=` or `=¶`, so behavior is undefined if such a string shows up in the input.
- Only shortcuts available in Japt 1.4.5 (most recent version at time of posting) need to be handled
- Non-unicode shortcuts like `_` and `@` don't need to be handled
- I've replaced easy-to-miss trailing spaces with `␠` where I found them. Those should be the literal space character ' ' when running tests or replacements. [Sandbox: Seriously, is there some better way to do this?]

### Test Cases

```
?OvUf\l m_c %H} qV):0 => "?OvUf\l ®c %HÃqV):0"
Ov"y m_î íZ c p0} "p2␠ => Ov"y ®î íZ c p0Ã"²
=== => ¶
ñgJ òXYZ{XgJ <YgJ } mg mg␠ => ñÌòÈÌ<YÌÃmÎmÎ
w å+ m@Vå+ m+S+Xw} c => w å+ £Vå+ m+S+XwÃc
```

[Sandbox: The first two test cases are grabbed from some real Code Golf answers [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166442/71434) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128272/71434). Should I replace them with something else?]

For reference, here is the full list of Unicode Shortcuts to be supported. It can also be found on the [Japt Interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/). Note that some shortcuts end in a space. [Sandbox: should I format this differently?]

```
¡   Um@
¢   Us2␠
£   m@
¤   s2␠
¥   ==
¦   !=
§   <=
¨   >=
©   &&
ª   ||
«   &&!
¬   q␠
®   m_
¯   s0,
°   ++
±   +=
²   p2␠
³   p3␠
´   --
µ   -=
¶   ===
·   qR␠
¸   qS␠
¹   )␠
º   ((
»   (((
¼   .25
½   .5
¾   .75
À   !==
Á   >>>
Â   ~~
Ã   }␠
Ä   +1
Å   s1␠
Æ   o@
Ç   o_
È   XYZ{X
É   -1
Ê   l␠
Ë   mDEF{D
Ì   gJ␠
Í   n2␠
Î   g␠
Ï   XYZ{Y
Ð   $new Date($
Ñ   *2
×   r*1␠
```

Comment: Nice idea! You can include trailing spaces by using `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` instead of indenting, though they'll only be visible if the text is selected if you do it that way. (Also, `Ê`, `Ì`, and `Í` want their `␠`s back ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

## Role reversal

*This is related to [an old question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23476/swap-genders-on-this-page-code-golf), but is different enough that answers should be quite different to the older one.*

You are given a sentence referring to two different people. Return the sentence with the roles reversed.

For example, for the input `I will give you a kiss.`, you should return `You will give me a kiss.`

There will always be exactly two people referred to in the sentence, and they will be referred to with different pronouns. Here's a table of the pronouns that might be used (pronouns in a row refer to the same person. Pronouns in a column can be switched with one another to reverse a role).

```
 I         me       my           mine         myself
 you       you      your         yours        yourself     
 she       her      her          hers         herself
 he        him      his          his          himself      
 they      them     their        theirs       themselves
```

Capitalisation matters (the first letter of the sentence should be capitalised, the pronoun "I" should always be capitalised, and no other pronoun is capitalised when not starting a sentence).

Words/punctuation not appearing in the pronoun table above shouldn't be changed. A pronoun word shouldn't be replaced if it appears as a substring of another word (e.g. 'history' shouldn't he changed). None of the inputs will be contractions using pronouns (so there won't be any inputs with "I'm" or "you're" etc).

### Input/output examples:

```
in: She gave them hers!
out: They gave her theirs!

in: He will eat me if I don't eat him.
out: I will eat him if he don't eat me.

in: Get it for them yourself!
out: Get it for you themselves!

in: I think I am going to see him tomorrow.
out: He think he am going to see me tomorrow.

in: I am not interested in history, is he?
out: He am not interested in history, is I?
```

### Rules:

- This is code golf so the shortest answer wins.
- Standard loopholes are banned.

Comment: Any last thoughts before I post this?

Answer (score 2):

A note about this meta post:

I just have one example right now, but I will have three in the final.

I thought it would be interesting to have a problem about something I know a bit about. Right now it seems a bit mathy, but I wanted to ground the problem on something real. It feels more 'real-life' if you need to understand the spec in addition to golfing. The problem is I don't want it to seem like homework. Another problem is the actual computation that needs to take place isn't actually that hard once you understand the simplifications of the problem.

Let me know what you think.

---

\$\def\tensor#1{\smash{\underline{\underline{\smash{#1}}}}}\$

## Challenge

Calculate the strain tensor and volume percent change of a cube given its material properties and stress tensor.

## Background

#### Common Terms

[image: Stress Strain]

- Strain: ε, The amount of elongation per unit length, Units: \$\frac{in}{in}\$
- Normal Stress: σ, The amount of force per unit area perpendicular to the cross section, Units: \$\frac{lbs}{in^2} = psi\$
- Shear Stress: τ, The amount of force per unit area parallel to the cross section, Units: \$\frac{lbs}{in^2} = psi\$
- Young's Modulus: E, The relationship between stress and strain: \$σ = Eε\$, Units: psi

[image: Poisson]

- Poisson's Ratio: ν, The relationship between strain in different directions. 
  For a uniaxial bar: \$ε_{22} = -ν ε_{11}\$, Units: unitless
- Index Notation: A short form for tensors written with subscripts \$i,j,k,l\$ to denote which element within the tensor. The number of subscripts the tensor has indicates what order it is. \$σ_{ij} \equiv \tensor{σ}\$ (Second Order)
- Kroniker Delta: \$δ_{ij}\$, has the value of 1 if i=j, otherwise its value is 0. Index Notation for the Identity Tensor.

$$
δ_{ij} = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
δ_{11} & δ_{12} & δ_{13}\\
δ_{21} & δ_{22} & δ_{23}\\
δ_{31} & δ_{32} & δ_{33}\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right] = I
$$

#### Tensors

A tensor in this context can be thought of as three directional components for each of the three positive faces of the cube.

[image: Tensor on Cube]

Although a [Stress Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) is not a matrix, it can be represented in matrix form by a 3x3 or other matrices:

$${\tensor{σ}} =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
σ_{xx} & σ_{xy} & σ_{xz}\\
σ_{yx} & σ_{yy} & σ_{yz}\\
σ_{zx} & σ_{zy} & σ_{zz}\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
σ_{11} & σ_{12} & σ_{13}\\
σ_{21} & σ_{22} & σ_{23}\\
σ_{31} & σ_{32} & σ_{33}\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
σ_{11}\\
σ_{12}\\
\vdots \\
σ_{33}\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
σ_{11} & σ_{12} & \dots & σ_{33}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

If a Tensor and a Kroniker Delta share the same indices, they are combined.

$$
σ_{ij} δ_{kj} = σ_{ik}
$$

If a Tensor has repeating indices, then it is taken as a zero order tensor and the indices are summed.

$$
σ_{ij} δ_{ij} = σ_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^{3} σ_{ii} \equiv tr(\tensor{σ}) = σ_{11} + σ_{22} + σ_{33} 
$$

#### Stress Strain Relationship

The relationship in one dimension is \$σ=Eε\$. For three dimensions we can use [Hook's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law#Hooke's_law_for_continuous_media) to find the relationship between the strain tensor and the stress tensor as follows:

$$
σ_{ij} = C_{ijkl} ε_{kl}
$$

This general case would need \$3^4 = 81\$ independent material properties to calculate the strain tensor. If we assume the cube has a symetric \$\tensor{σ}\$, symetric \$\tensor{ε}\$, is Elastic, Isotropic, Linear, and Homogeneous, then we only need [two independent material properties](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Elasticity/Constitutive_relations#An_alternative_form_of_the_stress-strain_relation): (Young's modulus: E, Poisson's Ratio: ν) or (Lamé modulus: λ, Shear modulus: μ). We can use either pair of values, but for this example it is much easier to calculate the strain tensor from the stress tensor using Young's Modulus and Poisson's Ratio.

And so we can simplify the stress tensor by what we know.

$${\tensor{σ}} =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
σ_x & σ_{xy} & σ_{xz}\\
  & σ_y & σ_{yz}\\
Sym &   & σ_z\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

And our new relationship is:

$$
ε_{ij} = \frac{1+ν}{E} σ_{ij} - \frac{ν}{E} σ_{kk} δ_{ij}
$$

#### Calculating the Dilation

[image: Volumetric Change]

The [Volumetric Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory#Volumetric_strain) can be found by calculating the trace of the strain tensor for very small values of strain. This is because for small values \$ε^3 \ll ε^2 \ll ε\$.

$$
{\frac {ΔV}{V_0}} \approx tr(\tensor{ε})
$$

#### Putting it all together

Therefore, in summary we can calculate the strain tensor with the following:

```
Using Index Notation:
```

$$
ε_{ij} = \frac{1+ν}{E} σ_{ij} - \frac{ν}{E} σ_{kk} δ_{ij}
$$

```
Using Matrix Notation:
```

$$
ε_{ij} = \frac{1+ν}{E}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
σ_{11} & σ_{12} & σ_{13}\\
σ_{12} & σ_{22} & σ_{23}\\
σ_{13} & σ_{23} & σ_{33}\\
\end{array}\right]
- \frac{ν}{E} tr(\tensor{σ})
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

---

Then calculate the volumetric change:

```
Index Notation
```

$$
{\frac {ΔV}{V_0}} = ε_{ij} δ_{ij} = ε_{ii}
$$

```
Matrix Notation
```

$$
{\frac {ΔV}{V_0}} = tr(\tensor{ε})
$$

## Input

One positive long: Young's Modulus (Usually in the range 100 psi - 100,000,000 psi)

One positive decimal: Poissons's Ratio (Usually in the range 0.01 - 0.5)

Array of signed decimals for Stress Tensor (9 values)

## Output

Array of Strain Tensor, to at least five significant figures (same format as input)

Percent volume change of cube, to at least five significant figures

## Examples

## (simple example for now)

```
Input:
Young's Modulus: 29,000,000 psi
Poisson's Ratio: 0.30
Stress Tensor: [[50000,      0,     0]
                [    0, -10000,     0]
                [    0,      0, 25000]] psi
Output:
Strain Tensor: [[0.00157,        0,       0]
                [      0, -0.00112,       0]
                [      0,        0, 0.00045]] in/in
Dilation: 0.08966%
```

## Rules

[IO is flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

- Stress Tensor input can be any size array, or string

  - Input type and size must be the same as output
- No formatting or units required

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), least number of bytes for each language wins

Comment: Looks interesting. However, because all answers are publicly viewable, challenges where the main difficulty is the implementation (instead of understanding the challenge) is preferred. Looking at the input/output it appears that the implementation itself is probably complex enough to be interesting.

Comment: this is very fascinating. IMHO the writing could be adjusted for the audience. if they are like me, i dont really understand stress and strain, and what they mean in laymans terms. also i think it could be simplified a lot.  take for example the first graph. what are the dashed lines? why are they numbered 1 and 2? what is 0.2%? why is there a cylinder there, and what does it mean? is any of that graph required to solve the puzzle?

Comment: @donbright Thank you, this is helpful. I will explain the fundamentals of stress and strain more, and annotate the pictures (which are directly from wikipedia). The graphs are not required to solve the puzzle, but they may be useful to understand the concepts. I have them to explain, but they are probably not as helpful to a layman. I will fix it up in the next few days. Btw, what do you you think of the explanations from the tensors section onwards?

Comment: I think it's "Kronecker delta" not "Kroniker delta". Also what is \$\varepsilon_{11}\$ and \$\varepsilon_{22}\$?

Comment: You should probably describe what is a tensor too. (yes I can read Wikipedia and it's unambiguous but it would be more useful if a post contains all information)

Comment: still hoping for this one to become a challenge!!!!

Answer (score 2):

## Haferman Carpet

Given nonnegative integer input \$n\$ output the \$n\$th iteration of the Haferman carpet.

### Constructing the carpet

- The zeroth iteration is `1`.
- When going from the \$n\$th to the \$(n+1)\$th iteration, replace each \$1\$ with the pattern `[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]` and each \$0\$ with the pattern `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`.

### Test cases

```
0 [[1]]

1 [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]

2 [[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],
   [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
   [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]]
```

### Standard I/O stuff

## Sandbox

Is this a duplicate? I will make the rules more explicit later.

Comment: Talking about replacing a scalar with a 2D array confused me for quite a while. Having the test cases laid out in a way which obscures the 2D pattern of the carpet also doesn't help.

Comment: As for dupes: [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfractal%5D+carpet+is%3Aq) are probably the most closely related questions: two about the Sierpinski carpet and one which is general enough to draw that one and this one. I think it's borderline whether or not this adds something new to the site.

Answer (score 2):

## DRAW me a picture: A QBasic metagolf challenge

[metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-matrix)

The `DRAW` command in QBasic takes a string argument, consisting of instructions for moving the cursor and drawing line segments, and produces the appropriate line segments on the screen. The syntax of the instructions is very terse--perfect for a [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) challenge!

### The challenge

Write a program or function which:

- Given a 2-D array of on and off pixels, representing a black-and-white image,
- Generates a string that, when passed to QBasic's `DRAW` command, will draw that image on the screen,
- While keeping the generated string as short as possible.

#### More about `DRAW`

Your program may use the following `DRAW` instructions:

*(more details pending)*

- `U` - draw line upwards
- `D` - draw line downwards
- `L` - draw line to the left
- `R` - draw line to the right
- `E` - draw line diagonally up and to the right
- `F` - draw line diagonally down and to the right
- `G` - draw line diagonally down and to the left
- `H` - draw line diagonally up and to the left
- `B` - meta-instruction: prepend to any instruction to move the cursor accordingly but not draw the line
- `N` - meta-instruction: prepend to any instruction to draw the line but not move the cursor

*(examples + pictures pending)*

The following instructions are outside the scope of this challenge and may **not** be used (even if they would improve your score): `C`, `P`, `S`, `M`, `X`, `A`, and `TA`.

#### Output requirements

Conceptually, your program's output will be substituted for the `...` in the following QBasic program:

```
SCREEN 9        ' Graphics mode, 640 x 350 pixels
DRAW "B M 0,0"  ' Set drawing cursor to top left corner
DRAW "..."
```

(If the length of your output exceeds any limits on line or string literal length, it may be split across multiple `DRAW` commands in such a way that the instructions are preserved.)

The program will then be run, and the output image compared to your program's input. Where the input array has a 1, the output image must have a white pixel; where the input array has a 0, the output image must have a black pixel. The portion of the screen outside the input array's dimensions must be entirely black pixels.

Practically speaking, I will probably write a verification script in some other language, just to make testing easier.

#### Details

Standard I/O methods apply. Output is case-insensitive. Input array dimensions will not exceed 640 x 350. *(more rules pending)*

#### Test cases

*(test cases pending)*

#### Scoring

Your submission's score is the sum of the lengths of its outputs on these test cases. In the case of a tie, the earlier submission wins.

Note: this challenge is probably a variation on the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), meaning that an optimal solution will take exponential time. In order to receive a score, your submission must complete all test cases, which means that you'll need to take a sub-optimal approach.

---

Sandbox questions:

- What's a good number of test cases?
- Should I instead score submissions on a second, hidden set of test cases to prevent overfitting? Or should the hidden test cases be the (first) tiebreaker?
- Is the implicit requirement "must complete all test cases before you can post it" enough of a bound on long execution times, or should I add a specific execution-time limit?

Comment: I would suggest explaining in what way the draw command is given its path length.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is my first time posting, so I need help fleshing out the details. I'm aware there are plenty of Roman Numeral problems, but this is somewhat different.

## When in Rome, count as Romans do!

This problem is inspired by [this](http://datagenetics.com/blog/april22013/index.html) website, which published the following diagram:

[image]

This diagram shows us that the longest Roman Numeral expression under 250 is that of 188, which requires 9 numerals to express.

The standard symbols used to express most Roman Numerals are the following: {I, V, X, L, C, D, M}. In this challenge, your goal is to, given an positive integer *n*, compute the number of valid Roman Numeral representations that can be composed through concatenating *n* of the standard symbols.

Then, your program must output the result of this computation modulo 3997 (to prevent answers from getting too long) in Roman Numerals!

## Rules for Roman Numeral Expressions

Roman Numerals originally only had "additive" pairing, meaning that numerals were always written in descending order, and the sum of the values of all the numerals was the value of the number.

Later on, subtractive pairing, the use of placing a smaller numeral in front of a larger in order to subtract the smaller from the larger, became commonplace to shorten Roman Numeral expressions. Subtractive pairs cannot be chained, like the following: IXL. This is considered invalid.

The following are the modern day rules for additive and subtractive pairing.

1. Only one I, X, and C can be used as the leading numeral in part of a subtractive pair.
2. I can only be placed before V and X in a subtractive pair.
3. X can only be placed before L and C in a subtractive pair.
4. C can only be placed before D and M in a subtractive pair.
5. Other than subtractive pairs, numerals must be in descending order
6. M, C, and X cannot be equalled or exceeded by smaller denominations.
7. D, L, and V can each only appear once.
8. Only M can be repeated 4 or more times.

## Test Cases

```
Input: 1
Output: VII
```

More to be added.

## Sandbox Users

Thoughts on this problem? I know it is really badly formatted but I thought the concept was cool. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So basically, find how many Roman numbers there are with `n` numerals? The modulo `3997` is probably not necessary, since the maximum for each `n` is only `8**n` (and valid roman numerals are going to consist of a small fraction of that)

Comment: Alright, I'll remove the modulo part. Does the rest seem plausible as a concept?

Comment: The reason for my inclusion of the modulus is because I want to ensure the answer can be outputted without using any numerals beyond those I've provided in the Standard Set

Comment: This needs clearer specification on what counts as a valid Roman numeral. E.g. are `IC` and `XCIX` both valid expressions for `99`? Is `MMMMMMMM` a valid 8-letter numeral?

Comment: I added more details to the text.

Comment: Now that you've posted this to the main site, please add a link to the challenge, edit out the body and delete the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Most distinct Turing-complete character subsets

*(Inspired by [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness))*

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

### Challenge:

In any language you choose, find the greatest number of distinct and disjoint subsets of characters allowed in that language (i.e. no individual character is in more than one of the subsets), each of which separately makes the language Turing-complete.

### Example:

JS (2): `eval()"\u0123456789bcdf`, `` []+=` `` (see answer to linked question).

### Scoring:

Scoring is by total number of distinct Turing-complete subsets found. Higher scores are better. In case of a tie, the answer with the fewest total characters used across all subsets wins.

### Notes:

Execution of arbitrary code is not required, only Turing completeness.

Explanations of why each of your subsets are Turing complete are highly encouraged.

In case this was unclear, whitespace characters are still counted as characters.

### Sandbox notes:

Should I include some stipulation forbidding languages such as Unary which don't care about the particular characters used?
What is unclear about this specification? Where could I give a better/more complete explanation?

Comment: I personally wouldn't exclude unary. I recall a previous challenge attempted to exclude all "symbol-independent" languages and it was almost as much of a mess as attempts to ban builtins. Sure Unary will "win" with a score of 256, but that doesn't mean no interesting answers will be posted.

Comment: You’ll need to define if spaces are counted as characters.

Comment: @JayCe done.⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Are you sure you want to use characters instead of bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## Chain Classification

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

<sub>[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/159629/31957)</sub>

**Objective:** Write a program (whose index in the chain of answers is \$n\$) which, when given any program with index \$i\$ (\$ 1 \le i \le n\$), outputs \$i\$.

(The program may do anything else given any other string input, including but not limited to: crashing, erorring, returning other numbers, sending an email to google support, and simulating the universe.)

### Rules

- Your program may be in any language *that has not appeared in the answer chain yet*.
- You may output to STDOUT, STDERR, return as a function value, etc. Any reasonable method of output.
- You may take input from STDIN, command line arguments, function parameters, etc. Any reasonable method of input.
- You **must** output `1` for the first answer, `2` for the second, etc. Any other form of indexing is not allowed.
- You must use base 10 when outputting.
- You may not use the internet in any way, particularly to scrape the answers to this question.
- No person may answer twice in a row.
- No person may answer within 1 hour of their previous answer.
- Languages which differ by version are considered distinct. Thus, Python 2 and Python 3 can both be part of the chain.
- Languages which differ by compiler or interpreter are **not** considered distinct. So, [Python 3 (Cython)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP/gQAA) and [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBAA) are equivalent.

### Answer format

```
# N. Language

    code

explanation
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run) links are appreciated, as well as links for the language itself.

You **must** include how your program performs input and output.

### Meta

The first answer is:

## 1. [Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin)

```
h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpzc3M@/8/A4gA) Input and output through STDIN and STDOUT.

Comment: An answer \$a_n\$ may also recognize every answer \$a_i\$, where \$1\le i<n\$, and, if it doesn't, output \$n\$.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yup. Do I need to edit anything to reflect that?

Comment: No, just a note that answers don't need to be generalized quines.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm not sure what would indicate to someone that the answers have to be generalized quines.

Comment: This is more like the comments that often appear below challenges for slight hints (usually posted by others).

Comment: What do the rules 5 and 8 ensure?

Comment: @BWO Rule 5 is for clarity; rule 8 is for variety.

Comment: Ok, I don't see a point in 5 but I don't have a strong opinion on it either and it doesn't harm the challenge. However rule 8 seems rather arbitrary, for one I don't think it will be more variable if a user is required to wait some 10 minutes before submitting. Even if in the mean-time another user will answer, I don't think it would become more variable: Just because it's the same user doesn't mean it will be nearly the same answer. But that's just my opinion, in the end it's your call.

Answer (score 2):

## The Input String, But Every Time It Says The First Word, It's Recursion

You wanted to create the ultimate replacement remix, but didn't see a way to add more recursion that ends naturally. Then you saw *The Entire Bee Movie But Every Bee Is Replaced With The Entire Bee Movie Without Bees*. Unlike the other replacement remixes, all the inserted copies were from the same text. It was the answer - at each recursing, you could remove the word being replaced, making each copy shorter than the one before it and causing the recursion to eventually end. Your master plan was complete, all that was left was to write the program to fulfill it.

## The Expansion Function

Let's define some function \$F\$ on a sequence of words. Words are sequences of characters not containing whitespace, which are separated by whitespace.

> define \$F(S)\$:
>
> if \$S\$ is empty, return nothing
>
> let \$X\$ be the first word in \$S\$
>
> let \$Y\$ be \$S\$ with all instances of the whole word \$X\$ removed
>
> let \$Z=F(Y)\$
>
> return \$S\$ with all instances of the whole word \$X\$ replaced by \$Z\$

Your task is to implement \$F\$.

## Input

Input the sequence of words in some form. You may choose any input method.

## Output

Output the sequence of words in some form. You may choose any output method.

Only the words in the output count for correctness. If you output as a string, the leading, trailing, and separator whitespace can be anything.

## Scoring

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

## Examples

Small case

> Input:
>
> ```
> b o o k k e e p e r
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r k k e e p e r o o k k e e p e r
> ```
>
> See the recursion:
>
> ```
> Format:
>
> value of S
> result of F
>
> r
>
>
> p r
> r
>
> e e p e r
> r r p r r
>
> k         k         e e p e r
> r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r
>
> o                             o                             k k e e p e r
> r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r k k e e p e r
>
> b                                                                         o o k k e e p e r
> r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r r r p r r r r p r r e e p e r k k e e p e r o o k k e e p e r
> ```

Large case

> Input:
>
> ```
> peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers a peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked if peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers wheres the peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> [218854 words](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7Cw_iX8MPMSpo2jzNtpaTOPkOh8i9MS/view?usp=sharing)

## Hello Sandbox

This section will not appear when the challenge is posted to the main site.

I can't seem to get the quote Markdown right, it might just be a parser bug where it thinks the quote continues even if there are no `>`s.

I originally put a description of \$F\$ as an implementation in pseudocode, but I'm considering finding a more mathematical description which tells you less about how to go about implementing it yourself. Still though, there is a challenge in optimizing this for tiny code.

Comment: I think the title is a bit confusing (as not everyone knows about bee movie or somewhat similar). Maybe "Recursive replacement" a better one?

Comment: Oh btw does "occurrence" means the whole word or being a part of another word is also counted?

Comment: Only a whole word counts. I'll go rewrite that to be more clear. As for the title, you're right that what the challenge is is more important than the inspiration, but I'm not quite sure what wording would be good. I'm thinking something like *The Input String, But Every Time It Says This Word, It's Recursion* which would state the premise while also referencing the meme.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the meme either. ***The Input** blah blah blah* would be better for others who don't know about the meme I think, but if you want to retain the meme that's fine.

Comment: The introductory paragraph primes the reader to expect a very different challenge to the one given: firstly because it sets up a scenario of infinite recursion, and secondly because it sets up a scenario where elements of the input are replaced by elements which are not in the input. IMO it would be better to remove that introduction and use it instead for a challenge which implements the scenario described and asks for the nth word in the limit string (although this may be a dupe, so check for that first).

Comment: I don't follow how the input creates the output. Could you show a step-by-step example of how each level of recursion works?

Comment: I added more details to the "bookkeeper" example, it should explain where each part is coming from, but it may still be too brief. // As for the misleading introduction, I attempted another rewrite, but I think it may need some more revisions before I get it right.

Comment: I think that the current I/O rules are just a little too restrictive. I would allow other inputs and outputs than "space delemited string", such as "list of words".

Comment: After a bit of thought, I relaxed the IO to allow other formats and methods. I figured you'll have some work to do either way, so I might as well let you choose the methods that result in the least bytes. I'm not too worried about dedicated data structures as an IO format, since that's probably already covered as a common loophole.

Answer (score 2):

## Triangular snake

You're given a triangular field:

[image: Triangular field]

It has 4 **ports**.

You're also given five different **pieces** from A to E:

[image: Pieces]

Each **piece** has a little piece of path inside it.

Your basic goal is to build paths between **ports**. There are some rules:

- Each cell of the field can be occupied by 0 or 1 **pieces**.
- A **port** can either point to an empty cell or be an endpoint of a path. That is, this is illegal:
  [image]
- The **path** starts with a port and ends with a port.
- The **path** must not be broken up into pieces, i.e. every edge of a piece through which a path goes must not touch an empty cell or a border without a port.

This is an example of a legal path:

[image]

This path can be represented as **"CBEDEAD"** or **"DAEDEBC"**.

### Input

There is no input.

### Output

Your ultimate task is to output all the possible paths. Your output must not contain illegal paths. You can output the paths in any readable way. Order, repetitions and letter case don't matter.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

Comment: Aren't A en E the same piece?

Comment: Yes they are, what a blunder.

Comment: It's sad you can only post comments with 50 reputation, otherwise I would have noticed that already :)

Comment: @int6h Out of interest ... What is the connection?

Answer (score 2):

## Iterated Prisoner's Trilemma

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

Please send me problems or else I'm gonna post this on main.

---

Prisoner's dilemma ... with three choices. Crazy, huh?

Here's our payoff matrix. Player A on the left, B on the top

```
A,B| C | N | D
---|---|---|---
 C |3,3|4,1|0,5
 N |1,4|2,2|3,2
 D |5,0|2,3|1,1
```

The payoff matrix is engineered so that it's best for both players to always cooperate, but you can gain (usually) by choosing Neutral or Defection.

Here's some (competing) example bots.

```python
# turns out if you don't actually have to implement __init__(). TIL.

class AllC:
    def round(self, _): return "C"
class AllN:
    def round(self, _): return "N"
class AllD:
    def round(self, _): return "D"
class RandomBot:
    def round(self, _): return random.choice(["C", "N", "D"])

class Grudger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []
    def round(self, last):
        if(last):
            self.history.append(last)
            if(self.history.count("D") > 0):
                return "D"
        return "C"

class TitForTat:
    def round(self, last):
        if(last == "D"):
            return "D"
        return "C"
```

Your bot is a Python3 class. A new instance is created for every game, and `round()` is called each round, with your opponent's choice from last round (or None, if it's the first round)

If we get enough entries for the result to be statistically significant, there's a 50 rep bounty for anyone who can beat Tit For Tat.

### Specifics

- Round count: [REDACTED]
- Standard loopholes disallowed.
- No messing with anything outside your class.

Comment: I have *no idea* how to embed tags in a post.

Comment: `[tag:something]` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks @Alion <3

Comment: Way too little substance. You should add a few paragraphs describing the prisoner's trilemma, the challenge, or anything else tangentially related.

Comment: Don't do a pretty payoff matrix image. Use text. That way you don't exclude people with limited vision who rely on screen readers.

Comment: How many rounds per game? And why does `N/N` suck so much?

Comment: @JoKing Haven't decided the round count, and probably will never tell. Don't want defect-on-the-last-round bots. No idea why I did that; if it causes problems i'll change it.

Comment: Maybe a random amount of rounds within a certain range? Also, wouldn't it be better for the second argument to be a list of all your opponents moves, rather than the latest one?

Comment: You can do watever you want within the class, so if you need to remember the entire history, that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

### [Posted: Find an array that fits a set of sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174252/56433)

Comment: I'd recommend showing the steps to generating f(A) (show each of the subarrays, then calculate their sums)

Comment: The last requirement: "any way that is convenient to you" is abusable, and basically removes the requirement entirely.  Either guarantee that there will be a solution, or require that submissions return a constant value (and add a test for it)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't get this last point. Maybe I should ask them to return a Falsy value?

Comment: Now that this has been posted you can delete it to make it easier for people to skip past it.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175118/find-the-minimal-initial-values)**

### Find the minimal initial values

Consider a sequence `F` of positive integers where `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` for `n >= 2`.  The Fibonacci sequence is one example of this type of sequence for `F(0) = F(1) = 1`, but any two initial values will yield a different sequence.  For example `F(0) = 3, F(1) = 1` produces these terms.

```
3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 14, 23, 37, 60, 97, ...
```

#### Challenge

The task is to find `F(0)` and `F(1)` that minimize `F(0) + F(1)` given some term of a sequence `F(n)`.  Write a function or complete program to complete the task.

#### Input

Input is a single positive integer, `F(n)`.  It may be accepted as a parameter or from standard input.  Any reasonable representation is allowed, including direct integer or string representations.

Invalid inputs need not be considered.

#### Output

The output will be two positive integers, `F(0)` and `F(1)`.  Any reasonable format is acceptable.  Here are some examples of reasonable formats.

- Written on separate lines to standard output
- Formatted on standard output as a delimited 2-element list
- Returned as a tuple or 2-element array of integers from a function

#### Examples

```
60  -> [3, 1]
37  -> [3, 1]
13  -> [1, 1]
26  -> [2, 2]
4   -> [2, 1]
5   -> [1, 1]
6   -> [2, 2]
7   -> [2, 1]
12  -> [3, 2]
1   -> [1, 1]
```

#### Scoring

This is code golf.  The score is calculated by bytes of source code.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58419/42545) :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions:  I haven't seen that one before, and the domain is basically identical.  But I still think the challenge is sufficiently distinct, since it's an optimization problem as opposed to straight forward sequence generation.

Comment: @nwellnhof:  That was an oversight.  I fixed it and added some examples explicitly showing `F(0) > F(1)`.

Comment: Spec seems watertight to me.

Comment: In general, if m<n, you can always replace [m,n] with [n-m,m] for a better solution, so F(0) >= F(1) for all optimal solutions.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Yes, I see now.  I've adjusted more of the test cases, and am considering removing the part about ambiguous solutions if it's irrelevant.   I don't have any examples then where there multiple distinct optimal solutions.  It kind of feels like that can't happen, but I don't have a proof to that effect.  If I can sufficiently convince myself it is impossible, I'll remove the part about ambiguous solutions.

Comment: I believe I came up with a proof of uniqueness. I think it may not fit in a comment well, but the basic idea is to write any one of these sequences as `s_k = f_k-2 s_21 + f_k-1 s_2` where `f_k` is the sequence starting with `1, 0` at `k = -1, 0` instead of the usual indices. Then it is pretty clear that if two distinct sequences reached the same value at the same index, they must differ from each other by a constant times a ratio of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. This is only an integer for the pair `1,1` and all such ambiguities are handled by you excluding 0 as a starting value.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman:  I removed the part about ambiguous solutions.  I'm not following your proof outline at the moment, but I'll take your word for it.  :)

Comment: I was bored so [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX3r9.jpg) the full thing. I wound up changing some stuff around so hopefully it is easier to follow. Obviously I could have messed up so if anyone notices anything wrong let me know!

Answer (score 2):

## Implement LogiMuxi [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

### The language

LogiMuxi is, as its name suggests, a programming language based on [multiplexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer).

#### Built-in gates

- `M(A,B,C)` (**Multiplexer**): If `A` is `0`, returns is `B`, otherwise returns `C`.
- `R()` (**Random**): Returns either `0` or `1` uniformly randomly.
- `I()` (**Input**): Reads a bit from STDIN and returns it. Terminates program execution on EOF.
- `O(A)` (**Output**): Appends bit `A` to STDOUT and returns it.

#### Literals

`0`, `1` are literals. Literals are expressions, and can be used as values.

#### Gate calling

`G(<arg1>,<arg2>,...,<argx>)` calls gate `G` with the provided arguments in order. Gate calling is an expression.

#### Conditional loop

```
G
 <cmd1>
 <cmd2>
 <...>
 <cmdx>
```

Evaluates `G`. If `G` returns `1`, the indented commands are executed, and this process repeats again. If `G` returns `0`, the loop is skipped. If there are no indented commands under `G`, the loop is empty, and, therefore, if `G` is `0` then nothing happens, while if `G` is `1` we enter an infinite loop with no way out.

#### Value assignment

```
X=G
```

Assigns `X` to the result of `G`. After that, the identifier of the variable can be used as an expression, and it will evaluate to the current value of the variable.

#### Gate definition

```
G(<arg1>,<arg2>,...,<argx>)
 <cmd1>
 <cmd2>
 <...>
 <cmdx>
```

Defines gate `G` to take arguments `<arg1>` up to `<argx>` (actual argument identifiers are specified by the programmer) and return the result of `H`. The identifiers of the arguments are localized, as well as variables assigned inside the gate. This means that, if I assign variable `X` to value `A` outside of `G` and then there's an `X=B` command in the definition of `G`, calling `G` will not assign `X` to `B`. However, inside the gate's scope, `X` will take the new value `B`. Assigning the arguments themselves to new values is allowed. Example:

```
X=0
G(A,B)
 X=1
 O(X)
 :M(R(),A,B)
O(X)
```

This will output the bits `1` and `0` in order. For reference, `G` chooses randomly between `A` and `B` in this example.

Gate definitons may also be nested, in which case they will be localized too.

Returning happens by prepending a `:` (colon) to a value (e.g. to return value `A`, use command `:A`). This will exit the gate and return the value to the right of it. You can't leave the part to the right of `:` empty. A gate that doesn't return is invalid.

#### Additional notes

- Commands are separated by line separators.
- An identifier has to meet these criteria:

  - The first character has to be in `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`
  - From the second character onward, the identifier must only be composed of characters in `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_`.
  - It can't be the identifier of any of the built-in gates.
- A variable and a gate may use the same identifier. They can be separated by the way they are invoked. Of course, this is bad practice, but this language is already pretty esoteric. ;-)
- Use of an undefined identifier is invalid.
- A gate is always to be called with parentheses, even if it doesn't take arguments. This includes the built-in gates.
- A gate may only return one output, and it must return one.
- Nested loops or gates are represented with the appropriate number of spaces used as indentation.
- Useless indentation is prohibited.
- Lines may be empty, but their indentation is significant. Empty lines do nothing.
- Calling gates with the wrong number of arguments is invalid.
- If the number of bits sent to STDOUT isn't a multiple of 8, the bits are post-padded with `0`s (e.g. if STDOUT is `00010000 11100`, it will be converted to `00010000 11100000` before actual printing).
- If 8 bits have been sent to STDOUT, they will be converted to a character and output immediately.
- Any syntax not defined above should be considered undefined.

#### Reference gates

*You may skip this section.*

NOT:

```
NOT(A)
 :M(A,1,0)
```

AND:

```
AND(A,B)
 :M(A,0,B)
```

OR:

```
OR(A,B)
 :M(A,B,1)
```

XOR:

```
XOR(A,B)
 :M(A,B,M(B,1,0))
```

NAND:

```
NAND(A,B)
 :M(A,1,M(B,1,0))
```

NOR:

```
NOR(A,B)
 :M(A,M(B,1,0),0)
```

XNOR:

```
XNOR(A,B)
 :M(A,M(B,1,0),B)
```

#### Simplification tips

*You may skip this section.*

`M(A,0,1)` → `A`

`M(M(A,1,0),B,C)` → `M(A,C,B)`

`M(0,B,C)` → `B`

`M(1,B,C)` → `C`

#### Sample programs

*You may skip this section.*

Infinite loop, no output:

```
1
```

Cat:

```
1
 O(I())
```

Hello, World!:

```
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(0)
O(1)
```

1-bit half adder:

```
A=I()
B=I()
O(M(A,0,B))
O(M(A,B,M(B,1,0)))
```

### Challenge rules

- You may assume you'll not receive an invalid program, or a program with input that will make it do invalid actions, so you don't need to check it for validity.
- The program can be either separated by line separators, or given as a list of lines. Acceptable line separators are `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` (`\n` denotes character 0x0A, `\r` denotes character 0x0D).
- Input can be taken in any reasonable form explicitly separated from the program, not necessarily from STDIN. Also, it can either be the actual input, or its bits (e.g. you can take `0100000001000001` instead of `@A`). It's guaranteed to be finite for this challenge.
- Output can be provided in any reasonable form, either as bits or as text. Also, you don't actually need to output while the program is executing, unlike what the specification above says.
- You may use any four distinct identifiers for the built-in gates `M`, `R`, `I` and `O`. Identifier rules will apply to your chosen identifiers in this case.
- You may use `[]` instead of `()`, and/or tabs instead of spaces in indentation. You must be consistent with these choices.

Answer (score 2):

## Squish these Numbers

**META:** I think my wording is not very clear, if you have a suggestion to make it easier to understand, feel free add a commment or edit it directly in to this post.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

Given a finite sequence of real floating point numbers, map it into the Interval \$[-1,1]\$, such that the order of these numbers is preserved.

#### Details

- You can choose any mapping you like, it doesn't have to be linear.
- The mapping you choose doesn't have to stem from a function, that means some number \$x\in \mathbb R\$ doesn't have to get mapped to the same number in \$[-1,1]\$, the value it does get mapped to can change depending on the other values in the input list.
- Two equal values in the input list, should remain equal in the output.
- If some value in the input list is strictly smaller than some other value, then the corresponding values in the output should satisfy the same relation, in theory. In practice it might happend that two different numbers will get mapped to the same output due to floating point arithmetic issues, which is fine - as long as it would work with an arbitrary precision.
- You can assume the input sequence contains at least two distinct entries.

#### Examples

Following example finds a linear map that maps the least entry to \$-1\$ and the greatest entry to \$1\$. Note how this map depends on the sequence.

$$ (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto \left( \frac{x_i - \min_k x_k}{\max_k x_k - \min_k x_k} \right)_{i=1}^n $$

Following example is a fixed function that always behave the same. Because it is monotonic and strictly increasing, it satisfies all conditions.
$$ (x_i)_{i=1}^n \mapsto \left(\frac{\arctan(x_i)}{\pi} \right)_{i=1}^n$$

Thanks @PeterTaylor for following example. Here \$\operatorname{sort}(x)\$ sorts the input sequence in ascending order and \$\operatorname{indexof}(u,v)\$ returns the index of the first occurence of \$v\$ in the sequence \$u\$.

$$(x_i)_{i=1}^n \mapsto \left( \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{indexof}(\operatorname{sort}(x),x_i)\right)_{i=1}^n$$

Comment: How about a function which sorts the array and then maps \$x_i \to \frac1n \textrm{indexof}(\textrm{sorted}(x), x_i)\$?

Comment: Yeah that looks fine (assuming for e.g. \$x_1 = x_2\$ we get the same index). - If you do not mind I'll add that as an example too.

Comment: I think many languages have builtin tanh which trivializes this. Are you sure there are enough languages where this challenge is interesting?

Comment: I expect it will be hard for a list-aware function to beat a general mapping like `x->1+1/(1+2**-x)`, or just `tanh` if that's available, but maybe Peter Taylor's method will be shorter in golfing languages. I think it's worth noting in the spec that it's OK if due to float inaccuracies two very close values are mapped to the same value in practice.

Comment: @xnor I'll add the comment about the floating point problems, that is a good point. I'm convinced that there will be a lot of different approach that will be optimal in the different languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Count smooth numbers

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

Define \$\Psi(x,B)\$ as the number of integers between \$1\$ and \$x\$, whose prime factors are all \$B\$ or less. (These are the [\$B\$-smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).)

For example, there are 34 integers between 1 and 100 that have only 2, 3 and 5 as prime factors. These are:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  8  9 10 12
15 16 18 20 24 25 27 30 32 36
40 45 48 50 54 60 64 72 75 80
81 90 96 100
```

Therefore, \$\Psi(100,5)=34\$. The next prime is 7, so \$\Psi(100,6)\$ is also 34.

This is a challenge to calculate exact values of \$\Psi\$ as quickly as possible.

### Methods

You may not use libraries or built-ins that calculate this function. That being said, I don't know any language that has a built-in for this (not even Mathematica?)

I also can't seem to find any fast algorithms for this problem, except for a basic [meet-in-the-middle](https://cr.yp.to/papers/epsi.pdf) by Daniel J. Bernstein which might be a good starting point.

Bernstein also describes an [approximation method](https://cr.yp.to/psibound.html) that may or may not be useful.

### Input range

You may assume that \$1<B\leq x\leq 10^{100}\$ and \$B<10^6\$.

### Scoring

You will be scored on tiers of increasing difficulty.

Each tier has several inputs \$(x,B)\$ such that the \$\Psi(x,B)\$ have similar values, and the \$x\$ values are distributed exponentially. Tiers will start at around \$\Psi(x,B)\approx 10^9\$ and go up to \$\Psi(x,B)\approx 10^{20}\$ or more, depending on how fast the entries get.

The time limit for each tier is 60 CPU seconds per input on average. In other words, if a tier has \$n\$ inputs, you will essentially have \$n\$ CPU minutes to obtain the outputs. You are welcome to submit parallel code but each thread will count towards the time limit.

Your score is the highest tier that your program can solve. If there is a tie, the program that is fastest on the highest tier wins.

For practical reasons, your program will be limited to 15GiB of memory.

### Sample tiers

Warm-ups:

```
3:
  Ψ(10^3, 997) = 1000
  Ψ(10^6, 7)   = 1273
  Ψ(10^9, 5)   = 1530
6:
  Ψ(10^6,  999983) = 1000000
  Ψ(10^9,  59)     = 1060717
  Ψ(10^12, 29)     = 1469549
  Ψ(10^15, 17)     =  919814
  Ψ(10^36, 7)      =  936046
```

Tiers:

```
9:
  Ψ(10^9,  999983) =  616220853
  Ψ(10^10, 4567)   =  954965955
  Ψ(10^12, 337)    = 1180049403
  Ψ(10^15, 97)     = 1016358704
  Ψ(10^18, 59)     = 1106651678
  Ψ(10^24, 31)     =  791377032
  Ψ(10^30, 23)     =  812060729
  Ψ(10^48, 17)     = 1435897064
10:
  Ψ(10^11, 11987) = 10016301575
  Ψ(10^12, 1499)  = 10753426440
  Ψ(10^15, 199)   = 12766644440
  Ψ(10^18, 89)    =  9052115006
  Ψ(10^24, 47)    = 11298682134
  Ψ(10^30, 37)    = 14838208717
  Ψ(10^48, 19)    =  7868307089
11:
  Ψ(10^13, 2297) =  84344528150
  Ψ(10^15, 443)  =  96272828440
  Ψ(10^18, 163)  = 107816435926
  Ψ(10^36, 37)   =  94053521936
  Ψ(10^24, 67)   =  81421195505
  Ψ(10^48, 29)   = 151266342065
```

etc.

I may choose to do the actual scoring on different inputs, including using \$x\$'s that are not powers of 10.

Answer (score 2):

## Shortest JsFuck code for a number

JsFuck is a language using only `[]()!+` to run and express anything in JavaScript. Below is a simplified model of JavaScript to express numbers:

- Types

  1. Number
  2. String
  3. Boolean (`true`)
  4. Array
- Functions

  - IEEEdouble(x):

    - Let \$u\$ is the number in \$\{a\cdot 2^{b}|-2^{53}<a<2^{53}, b>-1075, a,b\in \mathbb Z\}\$ nearest to x, maximizing \$b\$ on tie
    - If \$|u|<2^{1024}\$, return \$u\$
  - toNumber(x):

    - If x is a Number, return x;
    - If x is a Boolean, return 1;
    - If x is an Array [y], return toNumber(y);
    - If x is an Array [], return `0`;
    - Otherwise, x is a String. In this case,
    - If x matches `/^([\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.))(?:e([\+\-]?\d+)?$/`, let \$v=\text{＄1}\times 10^\text{＄2}\$ (`$2` is zero if not present)
    - Return IEEEdouble(\$v\$)
  - toString(x):

    - If x is a String, return x;
    - If x is a Boolean, return `'true'`;
    - If x is an Array [y], return toString(y);
    - If x is an Array [], return `''`;
    - Otherwise, x is a Number. In this case,
    - Find \$p, q\in \mathbb Z\$ such that IEEEdouble(\$p\times 10^q\$)=x, maximizing \$q\$(there may be multiple \$p\$ satisfying the restriction, in which case choosing which one is unknown);
    - Let \$y=p\times 10^q\$;
    - If \$y=0\$ or \$10^{-6}\leq|y|<10^{21}\$, write it normally without scientific notation mapping the RegEx `/^([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d*[1-9])?$/`;
    - Otherwise, write it in scientific notation mapping the RegEx `/^[1-9](\.\d*[1-9])?e[\+\-][1-9]\d*$/`
  - x+y

    - If either x or y is a String or an Array, return toString(x) concatted with toString(y);
    - Otherwise, return IEEEdouble(the sum of toNumber(x) and toNumber(y))
  - +x

    - Return toNumber(x)
  - [] and [x]

    - Return an Array.
  - x[y]

    - If x is a String, return the y<sup>th</sup> character(0-index) in x
  - !![] and !+[]

    - Return a Boolean

A valid JsFuck code is always parenthesis balanced without two symbols `+` together. Expression in parenthesis is calculated before the one out. On the same layer operations go from left to right.

You are required to output the shortest JsFuck code that generates a given IEEE double (A possible output of `IEEEdouble`). Shortest generator wins.

It's fine if your generator runs slow, but beware of potential infinite loop if you `eval`.

## Samples

```
1     -> +!![]
2     -> !![]+!![]
10    -> +[+!+[]+[+[]]]
1e10  -> +(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[]))
0.1   -> +((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+!![]))
1e-10 -> +((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![]))
5e-324-> +(!![]+!![]+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
9999999999
      -> +(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[]))+(+((+((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(+!![])))
```

SN: Another way to ask is requiring to be testable and shouldn't be longer than a chosen generator

Comment: Challenge seems a bit too long-- maybe restrict the domain to integers? Also I can't see any competitive solution actually finishing for nontrivial test cases because they'd just eval all valid JSFuck strings in parallel.

Comment: @lirtosiast Do your "integer" mean safe integer? Also I don't see how it simplifies the problem much

Answer (score 2):

## Is it shifted?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)

Consider a standard US-International QWERTY keyboard, without a numeric keypad, and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> mysteriously missing.

< insert image >

The goal is to write two programs or functions that take no input, and each give a distinct output through any default output method: `Shift` and `No shift` respectively. The program that outputs `No shift` has to be written without use of the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key. The program that outputs `Shift` has to be written while holding the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key throughout. **Both programs have to be written using the exact same sequence of keypresses**. A valid entry would be `a1b2` + `A!B@`, if they output `No shift` and `Shift` respectively.

The symbols allowed for the "No-shift" program are as follows:

```
`1234567890-=
qwertyuiop[]\
asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./
<space> <newline> <tab>
```

The symbols allowed for the "Shift" program are as follows:

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+
QWERTYUIOP{}|
ASDFGHJKL:"
ZXCVBNM<>?
<space> <newline>
```

Note that <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> is missing, since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> does not produce a `\t` tab symbol in most editors.

#### Sandbox note

I think using case-sensitive output makes the challenge more challenging, but it might become *too* challenging. What are your thoughts?

Comment: This already appears to be impossible in most productive languages, so I would allow output in any case.

Answer (score 2):

## Touch-typing distance

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

**Related:** [Levenshtein distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67474/levenshtein-distance)

---

There are many different [string metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric), a simple one is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) given by \$\texttt{ld}_{a,b}(|a|,|b|)\$:

$$
\texttt{ld}_{a,b}(i,j) = \begin{cases}
    \max(i,j), & \text{if $i = 0$ or $j = 0$} \\ \\
    \min \begin{cases}
        \texttt{ld}_{a,b}(i-1,j) + c_\text{deletion} \\
        \texttt{ld}_{a,b}(i,j-1) + c_\text{insertion} \\
        \texttt{ld}_{a,b}(i-1,j-1) + w(a_i, b_j)
    \end{cases}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The avid reader may have noticed that there are missing pieces in the above definition, it makes use of a weight function \$w\$ which was never defined and the costs \$c_\text{deletion}\$ as well as \$c_\text{insertion}\$.

The Levenshtein distance uses an indicator function which evaluates to \$1\$ if the two characters are not equal and \$0\$ otherwise and costs \$1\$ for deletion and insertion. This does not take into account that a mistake of typing `u` instead of `w` should cost more than mistakenly typing an `e`. Let's try to fix this!

### Challenge

For this challenge we'll assume a QWERTY keyboard and only take lower-case letters into account. We will use the usual letter-to-finger assignment (left-most finger to right-most) `["qaz","wsx","edc","rtfgvb","yuhjnm","ik","ol","p"]`:

#### Left Hand

- pinky: `qaz`
- ring finger: `wsx`
- middle finger: `edc`
- index finger: `rtfgvb`

#### Right Hand

- index finger: `yuhjnm`
- middle finger: `ik`
- ring finger: `ol`
- pinky: `p`

---

Now, to define a new string metric we will use the following definitions in the above generalized Levenshtein distance: Set \$c_\text{deletion} = c_\text{insertion} = 8\$ and for \$w(a_i,b_j)\$ we will use the distance of the two characters plus \$1\$ according to the above assignments (unless they are equal, then we'll use \$0\$). Here are a few examples:

```
'q' 'q' -> 0
'q' 'a' -> 1
'q' 'w' -> 2
'l' 'g' -> 4
'p' 'a' -> 8
```

### Rules

Input will be two strings \$a\$ and \$b\$ which

- are non-empty
- only contain lower-case letters (ie. match `^[a-z]+$`)

Output will be the "*touch-typing distance*" as defined above.

### Test cases

```
"todo" "todo" → 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Irregular English Verbs

[text-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing)
[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)
[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Given the infinitive of an irregular English verb, output its **simple past** and its **past participle**.

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- No need to handle verbs not in the given list.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Example

```
fall    --> fell; fallen
beat    --> beat; beaten or beat
bereave --> bereaved or bereft; bereaved or bereft
shall   --> should;(no participle)
```

## List of Irregular Verbs

```
Infinitive;Simple Past;Past Participle
alight;alighted or alit;alighted or alit
arise;arose;arisen
awake;awoke or awaked;awoken or awaked
be;was or were;been
bear;bore;borne or born
beat;beat;beaten or beat
become;became;become
beget;begot;begotten
begin;began;begun
bend;bent;bent
bereave;bereaved or bereft;bereaved or bereft
beseech;besought or beseeched;besought or beseeched
bet;bet or betted;bet or betted
bid;bade or bid;bidden or bid or bade
bide;bade or bided;bided
bind;bound;bound
bite;bit;bitten
bleed;bled;bled
bless;blessed or blest;blessed or blest
blow;blew;blown
break;broke;broken
breed;bred;bred
bring;brought;brought
broadcast;broadcast or broadcasted;broadcast or broadcasted
build;built;built
burn;burnt or burned;burnt or burned
burst;burst;burst
bust;bust or busted;bust or busted
buy;bought;bought
can;could;(no participle)
cast;cast;cast
catch;caught;caught
choose;chose;chosen
cleave;cleft or cleaved or clove;cleft or cleaved or cloven
cling;clung;clung
clothe;clothed or clad;clothed or clad
come;came;come
cost;cost;cost
creep;crept;crept
crow;crowed;crew or crowed
cut;cut;cut
deal;dealt;dealt
dig;dug;dug
do;did;done
draw;drew;drawn
dream;dreamt or dreamed;dreamt or dreamed
drink;drank;drunk
drive;drove;driven
dwell;dwelt or dwelled;dwelt or dwelled
eat;ate;eaten
fall;fell;fallen
feed;fed;fed
feel;felt;felt
fight;fought;fought
find;found;found
flee;fled;fled
fling;flung;flung
fly;flew;flown
forbid;forbad or forbade;forbid or forbidden
forecast;forecast or forecasted;forecast or forecasted
forget;forgot;forgotten
forsake;forsook;forsaken
freeze;froze;frozen
geld;gelded or gelt;gelded or gelt
get;got;got or gotten
gild;gilded or gilt;gilded or gilt
give;gave;given
gnaw;gnawed;gnawed or gnawn
go;went;gone
grind;ground;ground
grip;gripped or gript;gripped or gript
grow;grew;grown
hang;hung;hung
have;had;had
hear;heard;heard
heave;heaved or hove;heaved or hove
hew;hewed;hewed or hewn
hide;hid;hidden or hid
hit;hit;hit
hold;held;held
hurt;hurt;hurt
keep;kept;kept
kneel;knelt or kneeled;knelt or kneeled
knit;knitted or knit;knitted or knit
know;knew;known
lay;laid;laid
lead;led;led
lean;leant or leaned;leant or leaned
leap;leapt or leaped;leapt or leaped
learn;learnt or learned;learnt or learned
leave;left;left
lend;lent;lent
let;let;let
lie;lay;lain
light;lit or lighted;lit or lighted
lose;lost;lost
make;made;made
may;might;(no participle)
mean;meant;meant
meet;met;met
melt;melted;molten or melted
mow;mowed;mown or mowed
pay;paid;paid
pen;pent or penned;pent or penned
plead;pled or pleaded;pled or pleaded
prove;proved;proven or proved
put;put;put
quit;quit or quitted;quit or quitted
read;read;read
rid;rid or ridded;rid or ridded
ride;rode;ridden
ring;rang;rung
rise;rose;risen
run;ran;run
saw;sawed;sawn or sawed
say;said;said
see;saw;seen
seek;sought;sought
sell;sold;sold
send;sent;sent
set;set;set
sew;sewed;sewn or sewed
shake;shook;shaken
shall;should;(no participle)
shear;sheared;shorn or sheared
shed;shed;shed
shine;shone;shone
shit;shit or shitted or shat;shit or shitted or shat
shoe;shod or shoed;shod or shoed
shoot;shot;shot
show;showed;shown or showed
shred;shred or shredded;shred or shredded
shrink;shrank or shrunk;shrunk
shut;shut;shut
sing;sang;sung
sink;sank;sunk
sit;sat;sat
slay;slew;slain
sleep;slept;slept
slide;slid;slid
sling;slung;slung
slink;slunk;slunk
slit;slit;slit
smell;smelt or smelled;smelt or smelled
smite;smote;smitten
sow;sowed;sown or sowed
speak;spoke;spoken
speed;sped or speeded;sped or speeded
spell;spelt or spelled;spelt or spelled
spend;spent;spent
spill;spilt or spilled;spilt or spilled
spin;spun;spun
spit;spat;spat
split;split;split
spoil;spoilt or spoiled;spoilt or spoiled
spread;spread;spread
spring;sprang or sprung;sprung
stand;stood;stood
steal;stole;stolen
stick;stuck;stuck
sting;stung;stung
stink;stank or stunk;stunk
stride;strode;stridden
strike;struck;struck
string;strung;strung
strive;strove;striven
swear;swore;sworn
sweat;sweat or sweated;sweat or sweated
sweep;swept;swept
swell;swelled;swollen or swelled
swim;swam;swum
swing;swung;swung
take;took;taken
teach;taught;taught
tear;tore;torn
telecast;telecast or telecasted;telecast or telecasted
tell;told;told
think;thought;thought
throw;threw;thrown
thrust;thrust;thrust
tread;trod;trodden
understand;understood;understood
wake;woke or waked;woken or waked
wear;wore;worn
weave;wove;woven
wed;wed or wedded;wed or wedded
weep;wept;wept
wet;wet or wetted;wet or wetted
win;won;won
wind;wound;wound
wring;wrung;wrung
write;wrote;written
```

Comment: So this is a simple lookup, meaning that the bulk of the challenge is compressing the data?

Comment: Shouldn't the correct output from `can` be  `could;was able to` rather than `could;(kein Participle)`?

Comment: @Adám what about simply `can -->could;` ?

Comment: Up to you. Using `(kein Participle)` makes the challenge more interesting, as it has the only uppercase character, and the only parentheses.

Comment: @Adám, no. It should be `could or was able to or were able to;been able to`. It certainly shouldn't be `(kein Participle)`: the spec asks for output in English, not German.

Comment: @PeterTaylor OP hasn't answered, but to me it looks like lookup KC, so the actual content doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @Adám Yes, I think it's a simple lookup, it can be other than that?

Comment: Imho, it would be much more interesting to take a *regular* verb as input, and output the past tense: Add "ed" or "d" if verb ends with "e", but change final consonant-"y" to "consonant-"i" and insert "k" if verb ends in "c" and double final consonant if verb ends with a single vowel followed by a single consonant.

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: @Adám Do u mean adding the rules, or extending the current list with some regular verbs?

Comment: I meant replacing the list, so the challenge will only concern completely regular verbs. It is of course your choice. I can also post this related (but not really related, just inspired by) challenge myself. Let me know.

Comment: @Adám Using only regular verbs would make it a very different challenge. I think this one _is_ interesting as-is. Even if these verbs are irregular, they do follow some rules of their own (such as `i` becomes `u`). You may want to identify and store the transformation rules that are common to several verbs rather than just do string compression.

Comment: @Arnauld can I use your comment to improve the text of the challenge?

Comment: Sure. (But maybe you should use a better example than just '`i` becomes `u`' and make it clear that this is not a general rule but just a rule that applies to several verbs.)

Answer (score 2):

## Shift right by half a bit [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

The challenge is to implement a program or function <sup>(subsequently referred to as "program")</sup> that takes a nonnegative integer \$n\$ as input and returns \$n\over\sqrt{2}\$ (the input divided by the square root of two) as output, rounded to a nonnegative integer.

You may take your input and output in any reasonable format; for example stdin/stdout, files, or arguments/return values would all be acceptable.

You are required to use, at minimum, the largest fixed-size integer type offered by your language, and if an **unsigned** variant of this is available, you must use it. If your language has no built-in integer type (e.g. JavaScript) you are allowed to use its default numerical type (e.g. floating point); for languages with no concept of a number (e.g. regex), input and output can be e.g. the length of a string.

It is not required to reject negative integers; a submission that returns correct answers for negative inputs is allowed, but not required. Undefined behavior with negative inputs is allowed.

You are allowed and encouraged to use arbitrary-precision integer types if you so desire, but the type must either be a built-in, part of a standard library, or implemented from scratch in your program.

Despite what the title might imply, you may use any rounding algorithm you want (floor, ceiling, nearest half up, nearest half even, arbitrary, or even random), as long as the difference between the integer returned value and the theoretical exact (irrational) value is always less than \$1\$ for all inputs that fit in your chosen integer type. All inputs up to the maximum representable value must return a correct output.

In a way, the job of this program is to calculate the irrational number \$\sqrt{2}\$ to the requested precision, presenting it in the form of an integer. This is why solutions using arbitrary-precision types are encouraged, but not required.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. Standard loopholes are denied. The program with the least number of bytes wins. If there's a tie, the choice of accepted answer will be at my discretion. That said, this challenge is not only about which answer wins; it's also about seeing how concisely the challenge can be solved in each language, and seeing how each language "prefers" to handle rounding. And for those submissions that choose to use arbitrary precision, it's about seeing how concisely this can be done in the language.

## Meta

The **primary** reason for the question is that I want to post my ECMAScript regex solving it. Currently all I have is an 849 byte <sub><sup>(very heavily golfed down from an initial 1159 bytes)</sup></sub> ECMAScript + molecular lookahead regex, i.e. not purely ECMAScript-compatible and only works on my regex engine, so this question can stew in the Sandbox for a while until I port the regex to pure ECMAScript at some point, and/or put the regex engine on TIO.

That said, I am genuinely interested in what submissions PPCGers will come up with for this challenge (including in the languages more frequently seen in PPCG posts), and will treat the hosting of it seriously. Also there's the chance that someone will attempt solving it in a more powerful regex flavor, and I'd be fascinated to see if this could be done in significantly less length than ECMA (I actually doubt it can). Or somebody could come up with a crazy solution for it in some other language that has limits imposed which make it hard to do.

And if somebody could think of a way to solve it in ECMA in fewer bytes than I have (or even just golf down my regex), that would be fascinating (or thrilling) as well.

I'd be interested in putting up a bounty for the regex aspects of this question, and would appreciate any suggestions people would have as to how to do this and how much the bounty should be.

Comment: The whole stuff about type widths is confusing and I think it gets self-contradictory. E.g. "*You are required to use an integer type of at least the precision of a native int. If your language has a native unsigned integer type, you must use it (if you're using a native type)*". Java has signed 8-, 16-, 32- and 64-bit integers, and unsigned 16-bit integers. Which should it use? What does "*native int*" even mean in the context of languages which aren't C? Why should I get a better score in C if I'm using an underpowered computer which doesn't distinguish between `uint` and `long long uint`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor What I'm really trying to achieve with that requirement is increasing the likelihood that in at least some languages, simply calculating it using floating point, e.g. convert the int to double, divide by sqrt(2) and convert back to int, would lose precision, making it necessary to implement the sqrt function in integer math. But I wanted to not actually prohibit floating point from being used. I agree with your criticism though. What if I simply require that the largest built-in fixed-size integer type be used at minimum if it exists (or arbitrary-precision if desired)?

Comment: Thanks for explaining your goal. I'll think about it and see whether I can think of another way of achieving it. If you haven't already done it, you could pop into chat and ask the people there to think about it too.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterTaylor. I actually did talk about it a bit in the chat earlier, which is actually [why I required native ints](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48685539#48685539) in the original version...

Comment: I hadn't noticed your edit. That's probably as good a solution as is possible. One other minor suggestion: how about changing the title to "**Shift right by half a bit**"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I *love* your title suggestion. Thank you so much! I kept the text "divide by the square root of two" and moved it to the description, in case of Math Processing Errors and also so it will show up in searches more easily.

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Answer (score 2):

## Generate a 3D spiral

*Inspired by [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48767657#48767657)*

The spiral used in [The Path Of The Wildebeest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179157/the-path-of-the-wildebeest) is a contiguous mapping of the positive integers to lattice points in 2D. Your task is to generalize this to 3D.

Specifically, create a function \$f\$ from \$\mathbb Z^+\$ to \$ \mathbb Z^3\$ with the following properties:

- \$f\$ is a bijection (All points are eventually reached).
- \$f(1) = (0,0,0)\$ (The spiral starts at the origin).
- \$ |f(n+1) - f(n)| = 1\$ (The spiral is contiguous).
- The Chebyshev distance from the origin \$ |f(n)|_\infty \$ is a nondecreasing function (\$f\$ fills all points in each concentric cubical shell \$k\$ before moving to shell \$k+1\$).

One possible \$f\$ is given by [this Python implementation](https://example.com), but any \$f\$ that satisfies the above properties is allowed. Please describe the function your answer generates.

Because all your computer's memory is taken up by the wildebeest simulation you're running, typing is very slow, so your code must be as short as possible.

#### I/O

As is standard with [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions, either 1-indexing or 0-indexing is allowed. Any of these I/O formats are acceptable:

- Receive \$n\$ as input and output the \$n\$th point in the sequence
- Receive \$n\$ as input and output the first \$n\$ points
- Take no input and output the sequence infinitely.

Comment: Editing this from "is an increasing function" to "is a nondecreasing function" doesn't fix the problem... the function will sometimes have to decrease, because it has to hop over its own path and come back down. If you're already taking this into account, could you please be clearer about what you mean?

Comment: @Deadcode I'm not sure what you mean by hopping over its own path. This challenge is just to generate the spiral, not the path of any chess piece.

Comment: Okay, imagine an actual ball of yarn. But to simplify things, let's imagine you start with a sphere. Start wrapping a string around it. After you make 1 revolution, you must adjust the angle of the string so that it crosses over its previous path. This will make a small bump in the path the string takes on its 2nd revolution. And on its 3rd revolution, there will be more bumps. Now imagine the analogy with a cube, quantizing the path to a cubical grid. The 2nd revolution will have to cross over the path the 1st revolution took, making a bump, 1 up, 1 down.

Comment: I think in the cubical case, the path of the yarn can be arranged such that it never goes over bumps.

Comment: Okay, but then it will bear much less resemblance to a ball of yarn.

Comment: @Deadcode the key point here is that it's the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) that's non-decreasing. So the 3d lattice is divided into cubic shells centered on the 0 point, and the function has to map to all of the points in shell n before moving on to shell n+1

Comment: (in that sense it's analogous to the 2d case)

Answer (score 2):

## Least efficient field order

### Background:

In C and other languages, a `struct` is a data type composed of fields of other data types. These fields may be different sizes (in bytes) and may have different alignment requirements (e.g. an `int` field may need to be on a 4-byte boundary).

Padding is added to a `struct` to keep all of its fields aligned, and to keep its size a multiple of each field's alignment.

For example:

```
struct test {
    char  a; // 1-byte, 1-byte aligned
    short b; // 2-byte, 2-byte aligned
    int   c; // 4-byte, 4-byte aligned
}
```

In this `struct`, there will be 1 byte of padding after `a` (to keep `b` on a 2-byte boundary), no padding after `b` (as `c` is already on a 4-byte boundary) and no padding after `c` (as the size is already a multiple of 2 and 4 bytes), so the total size of the `struct` is 8 bytes (1 + 2 + 4 + 2). However, if we rearrange the order of the fields, the struct size can be bigger.

```
struct test_2 {
    char  d; // 1-byte, 1-byte aligned
    int   e; // 4-byte, 4-byte aligned
    short f; // 2-byte, 2-byte aligned
}
```

In this `struct`, there will be 3 bytes of padding after `d` (to keep `e` on a 4-byte boundary) and there will be 2 bytes of padding after `f` (to keep the size a multiple of 2 and 4 bytes), so the total size of this struct is 12 bytes (1 + 4 + 2 + 3 + 2).

### Challenge:

Given a list of pairs of positive integers (each pair representing the size and alignment of a field), return the same pairs in an order such that a struct with fields in that order would require the most padding, i.e. be the least space-efficient.

Givens:

- A field's size will always be greater than or equal to its alignment. (e.g. (4, 8) is not a valid input pair)
- A field's size will always be a multiple of its alignment. (i.e. (12, 5) is not a valid input pair)

Test cases: (other outputs that give the same total size are valid as well)

```
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (4, 4)] -> [(1, 1), (4, 4), (1, 1)] # size 12
[(12, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2), (8, 8)] -> [(12, 4), (8, 8), (1, 1), (2, 2)] # size 32
[(7, 7), (5, 1), (2, 2)] -> [(7, 7), (2, 2), (5, 1)] # size 28
[(6, 6), (6, 3), (4, 2), (2, 2)] -> [(6, 3), (4, 2), (6, 6), (2, 2)] # size 24
[(1, 1)] -> [(1, 1)] # size 1
```

[Test case checker online!](https://tio.run/##bVRNb9swDD1bv4JwUcBO1bRJu7YIkB0HDBh2aW9ZYBgOkwizZUOS@zXst2ek5KRqsotl8z3y8Uvu3ty21Te7tWkbcG@d0htQTdcaBz@UdRKe@q5GCY/ohPimsF7BPNgWShNMj6V4dKav3AHwNAnj8XgphEPriqq0aGc@4iKQl8ReiCTLJhImuYTDeSvhNs@lh6b8HmH0PeXzQcLDwLmXcM@mLzElQHcS7thE580QeXpEedgLkG0yjeWXu6ELyqFxbVtbMRia0m2FWOEa6qrJRmrGPcjh8iufM5EoqoydMpWLhCj0ORGJM2@EJSV9aXx1HhzQkt5etqpGeDI9MuuINvD4OYISrq58DuNNtcrIJqEkEr5W2Dl4dG33ncRLp1rNoQy63mj2DTlv0BVWvWNG4wiTiFK33uBx0rsWybo1oKgrbCGdWm10TlxA3TcsQmFyVlFriH3PA9WXEtsv5gGASwp5yudaj@h8iuQMfrYvUG2x@g2c0rqv6@DSoHaUN7HskJ@lzN9Vl41sfigoiM7DwAKLwJOkY/bsP7nEwU4qiFEKPvQ94oT@PxNhVZTavqCxR0OgO7a/HSTfoWl65we5vzrRvRt4/hplh6F2lnaYHr5LneVRHfZ3HAekuS0/S4wtLXdm8JnywjlvIlXRlK8@sN9xkqLvLHbKF9fLQ61/SJB1w7IE9ZgM3HC/Wj6QD/xXCLIWhS4bLApG0qJoSqWLIp2F/eN/B4eKfiQ0G4dNR82lnNJzy81LaQYZw5LXqDOUcDaQJO3rap6mfr9w7/ZLp3BBbumoRr2nfviOMg58BucrH5nW6@Pq5KHBvsLPA@UE6PcBJDMPUrnY7f4B)

Comment: I think in your explanation (1 + 2 + 4 + 2) should be (1 + 2 + 4 + 1). The only thing I see about this challenge that is questionable is whether having separate alignments is interesting or tedious. Would this lose much by assuming each field's alignment is equal to its size?

Answer (score 2):

## The Minigame Challenge

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The idea of this CnR is fairly simple: The Cops must create a simple minigame (explained in more detail below), with a definite goal. That goal may or may not be achievable. The Robbers must then either complete the minigame, or prove its goal is not achievable.

### Rules

#### The Minigame

The Cops will create a *suitably simple* minigame with a *definite goal*.

Acceptable minigame examples are functions that take some input and return some output, with the goal being to either achieve a specific output, or make the program terminate or error.

Minigames considered complex (and thus unnacceptable) would be programs/functions that will never terminate in up to 60s (using TIO as a benchmark here), or that simulate complex games (such as blackjack, chess, etc).

#### Note: I'll try to expand further on what kinds of minigames are acceptable or not. Suggestions are appreciated.

#### Cops:

The Cops **must provide** one of the following:

- A solution for your minigame that achieves the goal, or
- A proof that the goal for your minigame is not achievable.

at least 7 days (168h) after the answer was posted for their answer to be considered safe.

If your minigame's goal is achievable, it must **always** be achievable, and it must not contain "insider information", such as a fixed seed for a pRNG, or pregenerated primes as factors of a number to be factored.

#### Robbers:

To crack an (unsafe) answer, the robber must provide either a solution to the minigame that achieves the stated goal, or a proof that the goal is not achievable.

#### Scoring:

Cops will be scored based on standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules, with the fewest number of bytes in an answer being better. Cracked answers will always have a score of \$\infty\$.

Robbers are scored according to the number of answers they've cracked.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/20260) are, as usual, forbidden.

## Challenge is still under construction

This is the first CnR I've ever come up with. Suggestions and observations are always appreciated.

Comment: This seems a lot like PCG inside PCG.

Answer (score 2):

## Challenge

Create a function takes in two 2-dimensional arrays of Characters (or Strings if the programming language does not have characters as a datatype) as inputs: `a` and `b`.

Your task is to determine if `b` contains `a`. If this is so, return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`.

### Sample Test Cases

`a`:

```
123
456
789
```

`b`:

```
123
456
789
```

should return `true`.

`a`:

```
code
golf
```

`b`:

```
thisis
code!!
golf!!
ohyeah
```

should return `true`.

`a`:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

`b`:

```
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
```

should return `false`.

Least bytes wins.

Comment: does the block need to be as-is? No lines inbetween? No characters? i.e. does `code\golf` appear in `code!!\trucking!!\golf!!\`?

Answer (score 2):

## Finding Points in Convex Hulls

Convex hulls are notoriously hard to deal with, so today's challenge will deal with a relatively simple premise: given a convex hull defined by a set of points, and an additional point, find whether the additional point lies in the hull.

Now, for some definitions

1. The convex hull of a finite set X, a subset of R^n, is the set of convex combinations of points of $X$.
2. A convex combination of points x1,x2,...,xn is a point of the form a1x1+a2x2+...+anxn such that all ai>=0 and the sum of all of the ai is 1.

## Input/Output

The input is rather flexible, as long as it contains the appropriate information to express the convex hull and additional point.

An example of a valid input format to express the convex hull represented by (0,1,2),(4,3,2),(8,8,8) and the point (5,5,5) is

```
([(0,1,2),(4,3,2),(8,8,8)],(5,5,5))
```

The output is a truthy/falsy value, depending on whether the point is contained in the hull.

## Remarks

There are a lot of packages and libraries that deal with convex hulls, such as `scipy.spatial`. Such libraries/packages are explicitly banned. Libraries that facilitate matrix computations, such as `numpy`, are permitted.

The winning criterion is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

There is no limit on the number of dimensions the points can lie in, as long as they all lie in the same number of dimensions.

## Test Cases

I will be using the following [tio](https://tio.run/##rVLLasMwELzrKxbnYhFj0tclkF5aSo@l9FZCEPY6XqpIQlrTuj/vSnISWnKtLkKzszOjldzIvTU309R5e4DQkBvr4BST0kAHZz3DI2o1GDWK49kMBzeCCmCcaLEDMrt@0Lp0FaRdrgXERR0Yy0CBTGBlGixTsTqJHVlpJRw2Z5vMkyKXPfLgTWbUHZl2F2IGjV@lk/eblRCLNwyMLSiPwD2Cs2Q4wCdmpOmx@SCzT1lidcwgmczMkvCEqKHzGLttNHNaNVkoIHhl2jiRPRr0iq2PqsQ9jHbwR5ta8Oy@iZOoZ37eyutVdRtvsHjQdrgIx73ijMXZkUnxkuS/5Gmy32WeuzmP85FWFs9p3i@5pZCisx4oTSU3z68yE0meOl4xDPov@5tcOV@/ZqspcCmr00eY8SoLynNZ/tYO7Et6X23lslhDsZyPV1spp@kH) link for testing the validity of solutions.

Some smaller test cases:

```
([(1,1)],(1,1)) - True
([(1,1)],(1,2)) - False
([(1,1,1),(3,3,1)],(2,3,1)) - False
([(1,1,1),(3,3,1)],(2,2,1)) - True
([(0,0),(3,3),(0,6)],(2,4)) - True
([(0,0),(3,3),(0,6)],(1,1)) - True
([(0,0),(3,3),(0,5)],(2,4)) - False
```

## Questions for Sandbox

Is code golf the best criteria for this? That might encourage brute force searches on every combination of points... any suggestions?

Comment: You mention R^n but all the examples use Z^n (which is much easier to work with computationally). Please clarify the expected input. Also, what about libraries for linear programming?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking of making it R^n only, since one can bash out the answer if it is in Z^n. And, linear programming libraries probably also should be banned.

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it is to bash out the answer. The weights could be rational, and it's not obvious to me that the denominators can be bounded because the entire system can be translated.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hmm, I'll think about how to revise this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a post to pre-test for a duplicate question before I spend the time to finish the full post and add test cases.

So, have we ever had a question for a "snake rotation" of a matrix:

```
    +--------------+
      1  2  3  4  5|
    +------------  |
    |10  9  8  7  6|
    |  +-----------+
    |11 12 13 14 15
    +--------------+


    +--------------+
-->  13 14 15  1  2|
    +------------  |
    | 7  6  5  4  3|
    |  +-----------+
    | 8  9 10 11 12  -->
    +--------------+
```

The ascii walls are there only for clarity.  Actual input/output would be normal matrices

Answer (score 2):

## How many right triangles can you find?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

## Challenge

You will be given an input represented by `x`, which is a string containing at least 3 characters. It will consist only of the standard numeric characters, 0 through 9. Your job is to find and output how many right triangles can be formed with the given numbers.

## Rules

- Numbers must be kept in the order they were given in. No mixing them up!
- The numbers for each right triangle must be consecutive.
- The order of numbers has to be `a` first, `b` second, and `c` third, and must satisfy the formula `a² + b² = c²`. `a` can be greater than or less than `b`, as long as it satisfies the formula.
- Decimal points may be added between any numbers.
- Decimals require one or more numbers to be placed before them, e.g. `.5` cannot be used as a number but `0.5` and `12.5` can.
- Decimals with at least 4 digits after the decimal point truncated to the third digit, e.g. `1.2345` would truncated to `1.234` and `1.9999` would be truncated to `1.999`.
- Numbers can be used more than once in 2 or more different triangles, but cannot be used multiple times in the same triangle.
- Multiple representations of the same value can count multiple times.
- Repeating zeros are allowed, e.g. `000.5` counts as a number.
- *All* possible combinations must be taken into account for your program to be valid.

## Example Inputs and Outputs

Input: 345
Output: 1
This can be split into `3`, `4`, and `5`, which, of course, form a right triangle.

Input: 534
Output: 0
While this does include the necessary numbers to form a right triangle, they are not in the correct order. It has to follow the formula `a² + b² = c²`, but in this case it follows `c² = a² + b²`. The order of numbers cannot be changed from the original input, so in this case no right triangles can be formed.

Input: 3415
Output: 0
This does contain a `3`, `4`, and a `5`, which can form a right triangle, but they are not consecutive; there is a `1` splitting the `5` from the `3` and `4`.

Input: 5567507
Output: 1
Because decimals can be added anywhere, it can be changed to `55.67.507`, which allows splitting it into `5`, `5.6`, and `7.507` to form a right triangle. Remember that decimals are truncated to the third digit after the decimal point, which is how we get `7.507`.

Input: 345567507
Output: 2
The first right triangle is formed by `3`, `4`, and `5`. The second one is formed by `5567507` (read the previous example for explanation). Numbers can be used more than once, so the first `5` was used in the first *and* second triangles.

Input: 51125
Output: 0
Because of rule 5, you cannot use `.5`, `1`, and `1.25`. An integer is required before `.5` for it to work.

Input: 051125
Output: 0
Unlike the previous example, there *is* a number before the first `5`, so it is now legal to use `0.5`, `1`, and `1.25`.

Input: 121418439
Output: 2
The numbers `12` and `14` would form a right triangle where side `c` has a length of approximately `18.43908891458577462000`. Because long decimals are truncated to the third digit after the decimal point, we would be left with `18.439`. This fits in with the original input, `121418439`. Additionally, `1.2`, `1.4`, and `1.843` counts as a separate combination, thus giving us our second right triangle.

Input: 10011005
Output: 8
Numbers count separately if they're represented in different ways, so this allows for (1, 00, 1), (1.0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 01), (1, 0.01, 1), (1, 0.01, 1.0), (1, 0.01, 1.00), (1.0, 0.1, 1.005), and (1, 00.1, 1.005).

---

This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: So if I understand correctly we do the following things: get all substrings of the input; get all 3-part partitions of each substring; insert a comma at each possible position in each possible partition; check any combination of three in order is _approximately_ truthy for \$a^2+b^2=c^2\$ (approximately, because the decimals have been truncated, so aren't exactly a right triangle in some cases). Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen almost correct, except you must find all combinations both with and without decimals at any given location. So it's not necessarily just adding a decimal point at every possible place; it's checking the results that would occur both by adding and not adding a decimal.

Comment: "Numbers can be used more than once." - Could you provide some examples of this or otherwise clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Beefster see the fifth example: one of the 5's is used to form two different right triangles.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to explain it would be something like "Right triangles that only use a subsequence of the digits can overlap with other triangles made from the same sequence of digits" or "You do not need to use all the digits for a single triangle and you may re-use digits that were used in previous triangles". What confused me about the way it's currently written is that it could be taken to mean that you can re-use a digit for the *same* triangle, so 125059 could be split into 12, 22, 25.059.

Answer (score 2):

## Reverse RegEx

Take a regex `a` as input, output a regex `b` such that, for each string `x`, `x` matches `a` iff `x.reverse` matches `b`.

Here, regex need to support such symbols:

- `.`(any character expect `\n`)
- `[abc]`(any character in abc)
- `[^abc]`(any character not in abc)
- `x?`(appears 0-1 times), `x*`(appears any amount of times), `x+`(appears any positive amount of times)
- `x{n,m}`(appears n to m times, `m` can be omitted to mean infinite)
- `(abc)` `(?:abc)`(group block, `()` can be referred while `(?:)` can't)
- `\n`(refer to the latest match of n-th group)
- `^`(begin of string), `$`(end of string) (or begin/end of line, see flags/m)
- `|`(or, choose one in some choices)
- Letters, `\n`(this `n` is char rather than variable, line-feed)

You need to handle flags `i`(ignore upper/lower case) and `m`(multiline, `^` and `$` match begin/end of lines rather than string). You can also just pipe the flags and make the containment of regex work for all possible flags, aka. you can [treat pipe free](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23568/). (They refuse to allow or disallow)

```
Sample Input    Sample Output
/abcd/          /dcba/
/[abc]/         /a|c|b/
/[^abc]/        /[^abc]/
/(.)abc\1$/     /^(.)cba\1/
/$1/            /10% of $10/
```

Shortest code win

Comment: What's the regex flavor/set of allowed features/inputs? Is it for a full or partial match?

Comment: @feersum Allowed features need discuss. To be a full match `^` and `$` can be added

Comment: Why is test case `/[^abc]/` there twice? Or is it to give two different example outputs? Since just outputting `/[^abc]/` for input `/[^abc]/` would be fine. Also, I'm not too familiar with this Regex syntax, but how does `/$1/` work, since `$` is the end of the match? And why is it `/10% of $10/` reversed?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen twice to show that same input may lead to different output. `/$1/` and `/10% of $10/` both match nothing

Comment: "_both match nothing_" Ah ok.. I falsely assumed the regex would match something. So incorrect (but still valid) regexes are also allowed as input. Maybe it's a good idea to add some comments to the sample outputs, like `/10% of $10/` can be anything as long as it doesn't match anything (and maybe put the `/(?!a)[^bc]/ or /[^abc]/` for the same input on one line.

Comment: You should more rigorously explain what `x.reverse` means, from the examples it looks like you mean the order of letters is reversed, but some people might be confused.

Comment: 1) I think `x|y` is missing in the list of symbols. 2) The behavior of each symbol is underspecified in so many ways. What does `[a-z]`, `[[\]]`, `(ab+)*\1`, or `(((((((((((x)))))))))))\11` do? Do we need to handle any backslash escapes other than newline? 3) Are you sure this is possible? Can you reverse `(a(bx*){0,2}c)*\2\1`?

Comment: 4) Using such a complex flavor of regex is a parsing hell, which I don't recommend with the same reasons as [parsing arithmetic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19357/78410). Good challenges about manipulating regexes include [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197061/78410) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161108/78410).

Comment: @Bubbler I'll just don't care `[[\]]` and assume input only contain letters and `\n`. `(a(bx*){2}c)+\2\1` reverses into `(c(x*b)(?:x*b)a)\2\1(c(x*b)(?:x*b)a)*`(Handcode, maybe wrong; need some OR to fit your original one)

Comment: I'll ask differently: 1) Should we support range notation `[a-z]` or not? I assume it's not a set of three chars `a-z` since `-` is not a letter. 2) I think you have the knowledge that `(x)*` only captures the last iteration and `\1` fails if it is not actually captured. You need to include it in the post. 3) Should we support multi-digit backreference (like `\11` being the eleventh)?

Comment: A note for the future: a regex with backreferences is no longer a regular expression in the CS sense, and any kind of manipulation on it can easily fall into an uncomputable problem.

Comment: Also, about the "pipe free" thing: you didn't define the term "pipe" anywhere, so it only makes the challenge more unclear. "They refuse to allow or disallow" seems like a misunderstanding on your side; see Jo King's comment there. Basically an I/O method is allowed only when the language or the answer format (function or full program) supports it. And regardless of what site policy says, you can allow anything you want as long as you make it explicit (you already did here, so no need to mention the meta post).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the algorithm you have in mind does not handle `((x)|(y))+\2\3` (though it is reversible). I suspect it can be made irreversible if I replace `x` and `y` with something more dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

## \$n\$-Chess KotH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)[board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)

### Introduction

Inspired by the challenge [N-movers: How much of the infinite board can I reach?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179747/n-movers-how-much-of-the-infinite-board-can-i-reach), I came up with an idea of applying the \$n\$-mover rules in chess.

\$n\$-Chess™ is a board game played on a 8x8 grid like the original chess. However, the pieces are very different from chess - they are named \$n\$-movers (\$n\$ can be any natural number) and can only move by the rules set on them (see **Rules: Pieces**).

### Rules

#### Pieces

In \$n\$-chess, a piece is called an \$n\$-mover, where \$n\$ denotes its possible movements. Specifically:

1. The \$n\$-mover can only move one step of Euclidean distance \$\sqrt n\$ each time, i.e. for a move with \$x\$ units horizontal and \$y\$ units vertical, \$x\$ and \$y\$ must fulfill the equation \$x^2+y^2=n\$ in order to be valid.

   - For example, a 5-mover can only move 1 unit in one direction and 2 units in the another at the same time; while a 25-mover can move 5 units in either direction, or 3 units in one direction and 4 units in the another at the same time.
2. A piece can have at most 2 rules set at the same time. For a piece that can act as either an \$m\$-mover or an \$n\$-mover, we can call it an \$(m,n)\$-mover. An \$(m,n)\$-mover is allowed to move one step of Euclidean distance of either \$\sqrt m\$ or \$\sqrt n\$ or \$\sqrt{m+n}\$.

   - It is allowed to have \$m=n\$.
   - Only pieces that has captured other pieces can have multiple rules (See **Rules: Capture**).
3. If more than 2 rules are set on a piece, only 2 rules can be reserved. You can choose which 2 rules to reserve.

#### Board

The chess is played on a 8x8 board. The initial setup is as follows:
[image: Initial board setup]

#### Capture

1. If a piece lands on a grid that an opponent piece has occupied (capture), that opponent piece shall be moved away from the board.
2. After that, the piece will be granted rules from the captured opponent piece. As stated in **Piece**, if there are more than 2 rules in total, only 2 shall be reserved.

#### Playing

1. In a turn, White and Black play a move in turn. White always moves first.
2. Only one piece can be move per turn.
3. You cannot move a piece in the way that is not allowed by the rules set on it, beyond the boundaries of the board, or onto a grid already occupied by your other pieces.
4. You cannot move your last piece in the way that after moving it it can be captured instantly.

#### Victory Condition

The game ends with either player winning if:

1. The last piece of the opponent is being checkmated, i.e. no possible moves that can save this last piece from being captured; or
2. The opponent resigns and loses. (In this challenge, no resignation will be allowed)

The game ends with a draw if :

3. No checkmate is possible for both sides;
4. Either player has no more possible moves, but is not in checkmate;
5. There is no capture in 50 moves; or
6. The identical board arrangement has appeared 3 times with the same player to move.

### Implementation

A player bot is a class that implements a function `nextMove()`. This function receives 3 arguments and output an array of 6 integers:

```
function nextMove(
    color: int,                    // Your color: 0 = white, 1 = black
    board: int[8][8][3],           // Current board:
                                   //  First index: x-coordinate
                                   //  Second index: y-coordinate
                                   //  The third layer will be as follows - 
                                   //   [0]: the color of the grid
                                   //       (-1: Not occupied; 0: white; 1: black)
                                   //   [1]: rule 1 (0 if not exists)
                                   //   [2]: rule 2 (0 if not exists)
    moves: int[][10]               // Previous moves:
                                   //  First index: move number (0-indexed)
                                   //  The second layer will be as follows - 
                                   //   [0]: the color of the player
                                   //   [1]: is this a capture (0: no, 1: yes)
                                   //   [2]: source x-coordinate
                                   //   [3]: source y-coordinate
                                   //   [4]: source rule 1
                                   //   [5]: source rule 2 (0 if not exists)
                                   //   [6]: target x-coordinate
                                   //   [7]: target y-coordinate
                                   //   [8]: target rule 1
                                   //   [9]: target rule 2 (0 if not exists)
): int[6]                          // Return value: as follows:
                                   //  [0]: source x-coordinate
                                   //  [1]: source y-coordinate
                                   //  [2]: target x-coordinate
                                   //  [3]: target y-coordinate
                                   //  [4]: target rule 1
                                   //  [5]: target rule 2 (0 if not exists)
```

- Rule 1 and Rule 2 denotes the 2 rules a piece has.
- Source rule entries are used to denote which rules a piece has, while target rule entries are used to denote which rules are decide to keep.

You may use JavaScript, pseudo-codes, or any languages similar to JavaScript, but using JavaScript is strongly encouraged, because all submissions will be translated to JavaScript before using for competition, and the test drive only supports JavaScript.

### Restriction

1. Standard loopholes are forbidden by default.
2. You cannot by any means read or modify other bots. You can only use data within the class and inputs passed to `nextMove()` function.
3. You may define other variables inside your class if needed.
4. You may use a random number generator.
5. Your bot, specifically the `nextMove()` function, must return value in 10 second per move. Timeout leads to disqualification.

### Procedure

Round-robin will be used to determine the opponents, i.e. all bots will face each of the other bots twice, one as black and one as white. For each game, a win gets 2 points, a lose gets 0 points, and a draw gets 1 points.

The bot will the highest points wins, and if there are any ties, they will be broken by:

1. Number of victories;
2. Average time to checkmate opponent (shorter is better); and
3. Drawing lots. (Hopefully this step is not necessary)

### TODO

- Add a sample implementation.

Comment: KISS: since I assume that this is actually a game you've made up for the question, why not ditch checkmate and make the win condition that you capture all of the opposing pieces? I'm not sure about n-Chess™ for a name, either: it feels more like checkers than chess to me.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd say the question I had my inspiration from had its inspiration from chess, so I chose chess, and tbh I don't even know what checkers is until I've googled it right now. Well, it does look like checkers in the way capturing occurs, but I think I need to borrow some rules from chess, especially the ending rules, because I need to draw a line if the game never ends. Anyway thanks for your useful feedback!

Answer (score 2):

## Is this a valid Irish word?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

In Irish, most [consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_phonology#Consonants) are divided into broad (velarized) and slender (palatalized) variants, and the orthography marks them with neighboring vowels, which are similarly divided. This gives rise to the [*caol le caol agus leathan le leathan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_orthography#Vowels) (slender with slender and broad with broad) rule – a medial sequence of consonants must have the same class of vowel on either side: in *leabhar*, *bh* is surrounded by two broad vowels, so it is broad as well, and in *cailín*, *l* is surrounded by two slender vowels, so it is slender. *a*, *o* and *u* are broad and *e* and *i* are slender (similar with the vowels with the *fada*: *á ó ú é í*); *ae* is also considered broad.

Given a word, output whether it follows this rule.

### Input

You may assume that the input has only the following characters with their uppercase variants:

```
aábcdeéfghiílmnoóprstuú
AÁBCDEÉFGHIÍLMNOÓPRSTUÚ
```

### Tests

Valid:

```
deartháireacha
madra
nuachtán
gaolta
ceannasaithe
snámhann
fómhair
laethanta
béar
Bealtaine
hAoine
ball
tree
ggg
```

Invalid:

```
codegolf
delta
alishanoi
ABI
anseo
breithlá
```

(Note that *anseo* and *breithlá* are Irish words, but they happen not to follow this rule. You should still output a falsy answer for them for the sake of simplicity.)

Comment: Jebus, I haven't heard "*slender with slender and broad with broad*" in a couple of decades, that gave me a flashback! You note that "anseo" ("here", for the benefit of the non-Gaeilgeoirí) doesn't follow the rule but you should probably specify the expected output for it - I'd suggest against special-casing it and having it be `invalid`.

Comment: This needs a much better definition of what is a broad consonant versus what is a slender consonant, unless I'm not understanding the challenge.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork as I understood it, broad and slender consonants are indistinguishable in writing, the point is to detect consonants that would have to be both at the same time.

Comment: I'd suggest listing their `uppercase variants`

Comment: 'in *leabhar*, *bh* is surrounded by two broad consonants, so it is broad as well, and in *cailín*, *l* is surrounded by two slender consonants'. Did you mean 'vowels' instead of 'consonants' here?

Comment: Yes, that should have been 'vowels'.

Comment: I still have no idea what the types of consonants and vowels are.

Comment: This looks like a good challenge to me, to make it more understandable I would just explicitly list the sets of broad vowels, slender vowels, and consonants. (Rather than "here are all the characters: aábc..." have "here are all the broad vowels:aAáÁ...", "here are all the slender vowels:...", "here are all the consonants:...")

Comment: Also, you should clarify what should happen if the word does not contain a sequence of consonants surrounded by vowels (e.g. "ball", "thx", "tree")

Comment: "thx" is assumed to never be passed in as input. "ball" and "tree" would return true, because there's no contradiction between broad and slender vowels around consonants that can occur here.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Sandbox Notes
>
> - Any other/better tags?
> - Is my math right?

## Knot Function

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [knot-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knot-theory) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)

**TL;DR:** Define a closed curve in 3D space that forms a knot.

A function \$f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^3\$ is considered a *loop function* if the following conditions hold:

- It is continuous.
- \$f(0) = f(1)\$.
- It is injective everywhere else.

Intuitively, this means that the function traces out a curve in 3D space that does not intersect itself.

Let the set of loop functions be denoted \$\text{Loop}\$. One such function is \$\text{circle}(t) = (0, \sin 2\pi t, \cos 2\pi t)\$, which traces out a circle in 3D space.

A function \$f : \text{Loop}\$ is considered a *knot function* if there exists no continuous function \$d : [0,1] \to \text {Loop}\$ such that \$d(0) = f\$ and \$d(1) = \text{circle}\$. Intuitively, this means that the loop that the function traces out cannot be continuously deformed into a circle without intersecting itself.

### The Task

Write a program or function that implements a knot function, where real numbers are replaced with (to best approximation) floating point numbers.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (measured in bytes) wins.

Comment: This is going to need a formal definition of continuity, in particular of \$d\$. E.g. if using epsilon-delta, what's the distance metric between loops?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think it's pointwise fixing each input value of t that's given to d.

Comment: You need to be careful about input because it is not possible for a computable function to take an arbitrary *real number* between \$[0,1]\$ as input, so for this challenge \$[0,1]\$ is going to have to mean something else  likely \$\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\$.  You might also want to replace \$\mathbb{R}^3\$ with \$\mathbb{Q}^3\$, but I don't think this is technically necessary.

Comment: Also I am going to recommend the [topological definition of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) over \$\varepsilon-\delta\$ for this purpose because it meshes neatly with topology.  (and IMO is easier to understand anyway)

Comment: I think it would help to give a short informal statement of the challenge before going into the definition, so as not to needlessly scare away anyone intimidated by the math terms.

Comment: The TL;DR needs "closed", because open polynomial curves which are knots are not valid answers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Multi-Digit × Single-Digit Checker [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

## Introduction

*The story below is fictional, don't worry.*

Times table hard. More curriculum. Class advance. Son behind. Horror. Help.

*ahem* Pardon me.

So... I've got a big problem. The times table is huge, and all the mnemonic rules we've taught our son haven't make him fully memorize it yet. However, his class must advance to the next chapter, long multiplication. As a result, he is prone to making many mistakes while multiplying numbers.

See, they're already making the students multiply a multi-digit number by a single-digit number. My son often forgets to carry digits over and, of course, his times table. The good thing is that he never misses digits!

The situation is awful. Help me before they start with two multi-digit numbers!

---

## Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program that takes a multiplier, a multiplicand and a product, and analyzes the product for any of the following mistakes. Here's how:

- If a digit is the correct ones digit of the product of the multiplicand times the digit of the multiplier he's currently multiplying, but a non-zero carryover was supposed to be added to it, then this digit has a **carryover error**.
- If a digit is otherwise wrong, there's a times table error around it (we can't be sure if the ones digit was wrong or a carryover digit was wrong), so it has a **times table error**.
- There will never be another kind of mistake in the product, my son doesn't skip digits.

For each wrong digit, return an array of two or three elements:

- Position of the digit from the left or right, 0- or 1-indexed (your choice must be consistent). Keep in mind that, if the leftmost digit is absent due to a carryover error, then it's still the leftmost digit and the place has the relevant index.
- Correct carryover, if the mistake was a carryover error, or omitted otherwise. You may also put a `0` instead of omitting the element (you can't blame my son for forgetting to add a zero carryover!), but be consistent.
- Correct digit.

---

## Rules

- The numbers will all be positive integers.
- The multiplicand will be an integer from 1 to 9, inclusive.
- You can get the three numbers via any [reasonable way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/41024) you want.
- The output can be in any order, as can the elements of each array, as long as the latter is consistent.
- You may not make use of any [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024).
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest answer, measured in bytes, wins.

---

## Test cases

```
Multiplier, Multiplicand, Product -> Mistakes (0-indexed from the left, possibly absent carryover)

5, 3, 15 -> [] (15)
3, 5, 5 -> [[0, 1, 1]] (05 -> 15)
7, 3, 31 -> [[0, 2]] (31 -> 21)
1551, 9, 4959 -> [[0, 1, 1], [1, 4, 3]] (04959 -> 14959 -> 13959)
2121, 7, 14847 -> [] (14847)
2121, 7, 4727 -> [[0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 8], [3, 4]] (04727 -> 14727 -> 14827 -> 14847)
33333, 9, 11111 -> [[0, 2, 2], [1, 9], [2, 9], [3, 9], [4, 9], [5, 7]] (011111 -> 211111 -> 291111 -> 299111 -> 299911 -> 299991 -> 299997)
```

---

## Sandbox

- Is the challenge unclear?
- Is the output format weird or too strict?

Comment: I think it's a pretty interesting challenge! My only nitpick is in the introduction, when you're bringing up 'My son makes these mistakes:': make this section a bit more formal/a bit less story-level detail. The rest of the introduction is funny and gives some good context, but while reading the challenge I was kind of thrown off by the unnecessary detail in that section, e.g 'Ah, the crux of my worries.'

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi That might be because those were part of the challenge text before I decided to move it all to the **Challenge** section. I'll shorten them to one sentence. EDIT: I've removed that part.

Comment: Also, I think that making the carryover optional is quite confusing, and it also means that you have to check if it was a carryover error just to know whether to output it or not. I would suggest to make them always give the correct carryover or 0, even if it wasn't a carryover error.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi I'm giving two options for times table errors, either exclude the carryover or make it `0`. The answerer can choose one of the two consistently. Do you think there's an issue with the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188510/draw-recam%C3%A1ns-sequence-with-ascii?noredirect=1#comment451725_188510)

Answer (score 2):

## Print the sum of the previous answer's ASCII values

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

### Challenge

Output the sum of the previous answer's characters.
For example, if the previous answer was `print(25)`, the next answer would have to output the next answer would have to output 741.

### Initial Answer

The initial answer has to output the number 1000

### Rules

- Your code can only use ascii characters (sorry Jelly), no extended-ASCII or Unicode characters.
- Your output can be in Decimal, Unary or Base 256 (represented by ASCII characters)
- You cannot use a language that has been used before. (Note: Different versions of the same language are allowed, like Python 2 and Python 3)
- To prevent overly long languages (such as Unary) ruining the chain, your answer cannot be longer then 1000000 bytes.
- The same person cannot post twice in a row
- If two users post "at the same time", the earlier one will stand
- If a solution breaks one of these rules, it and all answers that chain off of it will be deleted
- Don't edit your code after you've posted it, otherwise it could invalidate code that chains off of it

### Winning

The winner of the challenge is whoever has posted the most recent answer, since it will get harder and harder the more languages that are used.

Comment: Can you clarify base 256? If extended ASCII is excluded, is there a specific way to represent 256 distinct digits using 127 codepoints?

Comment: IMO this is too trivial to make a good answer chaining question. Finding an unused language in which you can figure out how to write (essentially) Hello, World is not going to get difficult until a couple of thousand answers in.

Comment: Wouldn't every answer just be variants of `print(n)` where \$n\$ is the integer literal of the sum of the last answer?

Comment: Yeah, I’m gonna scrap this challenge because I didn’t think it through properly

Answer (score 2):

### I'm sorry, Code Golf

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

This challenge is inspired by a series of Garfield-inspired artwork in which Garfield is depicted as a horror creature, stalking his owner, Jon. Commonly referred to as "Creepy Garfield", the line "***I'm sorry, Jon***" can be found in one of the [earliest Creepy Garfield images](http://dubblebaby.blogspot.com/2013/10/blog-post_21.html), created by DubbleBaby.

*[William Burke's Depiction](https://www.instagram.com/p/BozsEZJHdSr/?utm_source=ig_embed)*
[image]

After being used over and over again by the Code Golf community, our beloved Jimmy has transformed - no longer bound to his weak, mortal body. He has become the embodiment of spaghetti code, the ascii manifestation of hours-long debugging sessions.

---

### Your Task:

*Take 3 ordered numerical inputs and output Jimmy's body*

**Inputs**

Input is received in the form `x y z` where:

```
x is the number of left limbs (integer between 1 & 10)
y is the number of right limbs (integer between 1 & 10)
z is the number of heads (integer between 1 & 10)

----Sample Input----
2 8 1
```

***Meta Note***: I don't think increasing the possible amount of body parts will influence the solutions but please let me know if you think they should be higher.

**Body Parts**

```
Head =          <o>
Left Limb =     /
Right Limb =    \
Filler Limb =   |
Body Piece =    0
```

**Body Generation Rules**

```
   1. Left limbs must be attached to the left side of a body piece
    (excl rule 3)
    - Correct:  /0
    - Incorrect: /<o>
    - Incorrect: 0/
    - Incorrect: /0\0\

2. Right limbs must be attached to the right side of a body piece
    (excl rule 3)
    - Correct: 0\
    - Incorrect: <o>\
    - Incorrect: \0

3. Limbs must not touch
    - Correct: /00\
    - Incorrect: /0\/0\

4. An external body piece without a limb must have a | in its place
    - Correct: /0|
    - Correct: |0|
    - Correct: /00\
    - Incorrect: /0
    - Incorrect: 0\

5. Heads must be between body pieces (horizontally not vertically)
    - Correct: 0<o>0
    - Incorrect: 0<o><o>0
    - Incorrect: 0<o>

6. All lines must be aligned centre
    - Correct:      /0\
                  /0<o>0|
                    /0\

    - Incorrect:    /0\
                    /0<o>0|
                    /0\

7. The bottom line of Jimmy's body must always contain a left and right limb
    - Correct:      /0\
                  /0<o>0|
                    /0\

    - Incorrect:    /0\
                  /0<o>0\
                    /0|

8. Jimmy's body must be whole and cannot be separated into sections
    - Correct:    /0\
                /0<o>0|

    - Incorrect:    /0\   /0\   |0<o>0|

    - Incorrect:      /0\

                    /0<o>0|
```

**Examples**

```
Input:
2 8 2

Sample Output:

/0<o>0<o>0\
    |0\
    |0\
    |0\
    |0\
    |0\
    |0\
    /0\

    OR

  /0\
  |0\
|0<o>0\
  |0\
  |0\
|0<o>0\
  |0\
  /0\
```

---

### Rules & Win Conditions

1. You may receive the stated input via any method into a program or function.
2. You may display the output in any clear and discernible way.
3. Your output must obey all Body Generation Rules.
4. The previous 3 rules must be followed for all 1000 combinations of inputs.
5. Standard loophole rules apply.

*As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), least amount of code in bytes wins.*

Comment: I don't like bonuses in code golf in general, and this one doesn't even affect the score so it's just an invitation to distract from the challenge

Comment: (1) Whenever you see a bandwagon, run the other way. It's better to ask an interesting question than the nth variant on a theme. (2) That aside, there's no clear explanation of what the input is. Where are the values of that enum?

Comment: @PeterTaylor (1) This challenge doesn't exist to hop on the bandwagon. I thought that generating an eldritch-like stick figure would be neat. **If you don't think this is an interesting question, I'd love to hear your feedback on that.** (2) I've amended the input section to be a bit clearer but I'm not sure what I was missing in the first place.

Comment: What's missing is an explanation of the interpretation of the numbers. The input section defines the range of legal inputs but not the meaning of the inputs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah I understand now. Hopefully my recent edit solves this.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49671/58974) ... I think?!

Answer (score 2):

## Minimum string attractors

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

---

## String attractors

Let \$S\$ be a string of length \$n\$.
An *attractor* of \$S\$ is a subset of indices \$A \subset \{0, \ldots, n-1\}\$ such that every nonempty contiguous substring \$S[i \ldots j]\$ of \$S\$ has an occurrence \$S[i' \ldots j']\$ whose index set \$[i' \ldots j']\$ intersects \$A\$.
A *minimum attractor* is one with minimal size.
Minimum attractors can be used to implement very efficient string compression algorithms.
In this challenge, your task is to find a minimum attractor for a given string.

## Example

Consider the string `acabaccabc`.
Using 0-based indexing, one of its attractors is \$A = \{2,3,5,8\}\$.
This graphic shows the positions of \$A\$:

```
acabaccabc
  ^^ ^  ^
```

For example, the occurrence of the substring `ac` in the beginning doesn't intersect \$A\$, but there is another occurrence after the first `b` that does.
It turns out that no attractor of size 3 exists for this string, so \$A\$ is a minimum attractor.

## Specifications

Your input is a nonempty string of lowercase ASCII characters.
Your output is a minimum attractor for this string, in any reasonable format.
You can use either 0-based or 1-based indexing.

There may be several choices for the minimum attractor.
In that case you may return any one of them, but only one.

The lowest byte count wins.

## Test cases

These are 0-indexed and show one possible output.

```
a -> [0]
aaa -> [0]
ababab -> [0,1]
qgqqgq -> [1,2]
abcbacaa -> [1,3,5,6]
abcdefgh -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
jejjeeje -> [2,3,5]
sttststt -> [1,5]
ykkkkvyk -> [0,2,5]
assassins -> [0,2,6,7]
acabaccabc -> [2,4,6,8]
ssssssjjjsjj -> [5,8]
hrhrhhrhhhrr -> [3,7,10]
fubuaabubuau -> [0,1,4,6,10]
jjaahajjhahaaahjjh -> [2,6,8,11,14]
```

Comment: It took me a few tries to understand the first paragraph. I think it is explained well, but I may just have been unfamiliar with the language. Adding an explanation of "occurrence" may help?

Comment: The formal definition in the first paragraph is clear if you are used to such an academic style, though it might unnecessarily hard to grasp for users with no such background. It might be worthwhile to start with an informal explanation before giving the concise formal specification. E.g. something like this:

Consider the following game: You are given a string like `acabaccabc` and need to defend it against attacks by marking some of its characters. An attack is a continuous substring of the given string, e.g. `ca`, and it is defended if one of the occurrences of the substring has (1/2)

Comment: a character that was marked by you. In the given example, `ca` occurs two times and covers the characters at positions 1,2 and 6,7 (with positions starting with 0). Thus, at least one of the positions 1,2,6 or 7 would need to be marked to defend the attack. Your goal is to find a marking such that the string is defended against any attack. Furthermore, you want to mark as few characters as possible. (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

## Check If A Binary Search Tree Is Balanced

Now posted on CodeGolf.StackExchange.com:

[Write The Shortest Program To Check If A Binary Tree Is Balanced](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189285/write-the-shortest-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced)

Comment: Looks like a nice challenge! I think you should specify what representations of a binary tree are accepted. There is certainly the representation as a list (where the children of the entry at index `r` are at `2*r` and `2*r+1`), but there might also be other native representations.

Comment: Now that you've posted this, please edit it to be only a link to the main challenge and then delete your post to help keep the Sandbox tidy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Posted to PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189471/decode-a-variable-length-quantity).  Thx for the votes!

Answer (score 2):

### Black Hole Evaporation

**Background**: In empty space, occurring all the time, [there are pairs of particles that appear and then, usually soon after, cancel each other out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). At a certain distance from a Black Hole, it's possible that a pair of particles might spontaneously appear and, if the distance is just right, one of the particles will fall into the Event Horizon while the other escapes off into space, never getting a chance to cancel each other out. The exit of those particles is [Hawking Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation). Eventually, this process causes the entire Black Hole to evaporate away.

**Challenge**

Given a string of numbers, emit the negative of the single digit number closest to, in front of, the infinity symbol ∞ (the event horizon), and continue emiting it until there are no digits left in front of the infinity symbol. Then print the rest of the string masking each character uniquely and different from the masked character (burst of energy that might take place at the final instant), excluding any infinity symbols.

**Test cases**

```
Input:                      Output:
111∞4567                    -1 -1 -1 jkl;
3∞                          -3
3-145∞962                   -5 -4 1 -3 ™©®
4-567-9∞1-23                 9 -7 -6 5 -4 
2-1∞                        1 -2
34∞67∞89                    -4 -3 9876
-123∞456                    -3 -2 1 ♫♪#
6-6∞6                       6 -6 ä
48120∞                      0 (or -0) -2 -1 -8 -4
---5∞555                    5 オゼヰ
```

**Challenge rules**

- Anything after the first infinity symbol can be ignored as it has fallen into the Black Hole and we know nothing more about it anyway until after evaporation, where the information is a bit scrambled.
- The code should only expect numbers, negations, and infinity symbols. No decimal points or other symbols. The input can be an array, list, etc..., but *each character must be separate*, including the negation and infinity characters.
- A negation only applies to the single digit immediately after it. See the test cases above.
- You may mask the remaining characters after evaporation with any character set of your choice, as long as the resulting character is different from the masked character, and each character in the resulting output is unique. For languages limited to smaller character sets (or type constraints), characters may repeat after each possible unique character has already been utilized in the output.
- You may use the '_' symbol instead of the '∞' symbol.

**General rules**

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes in its respective language wins.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN (with the specification above)/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code ([TIO](https://tio.run/#)).

Comment: I'm thinking of expanding this to all alpha numeric characters.

Comment: What does it do if there is a single number after the infinity symbol?

Comment: I'll update the rules and the test cases. Curiously, I already sort of demonstrated that case by having nothing after the infinity symbol. Nice catch.

Comment: If `121` remains after evaporation, is reversing that string an acceptable scrambling?

Comment: Any particular reason to use `∞`? Adding Unicode into the mix is an unnecessary complication for many languages. Maybe allow substituting `_`?

Comment: @Adam, "If 121 remains after evaporation, is reversing that string an acceptable scrambling" Absolutey! Our understanding of what happens to the information after Black Hole evaporation is still under much debate. It is entirely possible that the result of scrambling might result in the *same* information. We just don't know.

Comment: @Adam, "Any particular reason to use ∞? Adding Unicode into the mix is an unnecessary complication for many languages." Yeah I thought about that. It can even be excluding factor, which I don't like. I really want that infinity symbol though.... I'll have a think about it, but any suggestions like yours are welcome.

Comment: @Adam, "If 121 remains after evaporation, is reversing that string an acceptable scrambling?". After re-reading through the Information Paradox, I think the answer is 'no'. '121' should definitely end up different. I'll have to find some way to re-word the challenge, and I can be talked out of this. This requirement seemed rather innocent, but as I'm trying to code this up in my head, it can get complicated.

Comment: The connection between the background and the task is not very clear. The comment about information suggests that you have a much clearer idea which you haven't included in the question. There's no need to overload the question with back story, but a link to a more detailed explanation might make it feel less arbitrary.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I've been mulling over your comment and I'm not sure what to include. Links to the Information Paradox or Hawking Radiation, or both?

Comment: Probably both. AIUI, the infinity symbol represents the event horizon, the symbols to the left represent virtual pairs which become Hawking radiation, the symbols to the right represent the captured information, the emission of the inverted symbols to the left corresponds to the emission of Hawking radiation, and the shuffling of the symbols to the right corresponds to the information paradox. (I'm not sure without checking some reference why there's anything left to the right after evaporation). It would be good to sketch the correspondences and have some "Further reading".

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Ok thanks. The final stage of evaporation might release a detectable packet of energy (which has yet to be seen or is even theoretically certain), so that's *kind of* what that represents. There might be something left over afterwords, or maybe not. When I get the chance, I'll edit some links in and parenthesize some metaphors in there as well.

Comment: @ouflak Regarding `∞` you can use it but *allow* substitution. Btw, `_` is the [infinity symbol in the J language](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d030.htm).

Comment: @Adám, What about, "If your language has a built-in substitute for ∞, you may use that. If your language can't use Unicode, or use it efficiently, you may use the '_' symbol instead." Does that sound fair and inclusive enough?

Comment: @ouflak What if your language's infinity is `inf`? That's three symbols, so it complicates matters a lot. "use it efficiently" is unclear? Does that include causing higher byte count? How about just: You may use the `_` symbol instead of `∞`.

Comment: @Adám, *sigh* I'm not going to be allowed to preserve infinity am I? Alright, I'll edit it in a bit.

Comment: @ouflak Yes, use `∞` throughout your examples!

Comment: I'm thinking having a mask for the output instead of just changing the order. The mask can be the coder's choice, and it must only guarantee that it preserves the remaining character count. Opinions?

Comment: Ok, I've updated it for masking of the output instead of scrambling. I think this is more precise than simply rearranging the characters.

Answer (score 2):

## Find the Lowest Common Ancestor of Two Nodes In A Binary Tree

Any two separate nodes in a binary tree have a common ancestor, which is the root of a binary tree. The lowest common ancestor(LCA) is thus defined as the node that is **furthest from the root** and that is the ancestor of the two nodes.

The following are binary trees and the lowest common ancestors of the some of their nodes.

[image: Binary Tree 1]

The LCA of 13 and 15 is 14.

The LCA of 47 and 49 is 48.

The LCA of 4 and 45 is 40.

The LCA of 13 and 14 is 14.

**Challenge**

Write the shortest program possible that accepts as input the root of a binary tree and references to any two nodes in the binary tree. The program returns a reference to the LCA node of the two inputted nodes.

**Restriction**

The binary tree **does not** have nodes with parent field references in any form. You **may not** use parent field references in your program.

**Input**

The **root of a binary tree** and **references to any two nodes in the binary tree**. This may be in the form of a reference to the root object or even a list that is a valid representation of a binary tree.

**Output**

Returns **a reference** to the node that is the LCA of the two inputted nodes.

**Definition of a Binary Tree**

A tree is an object that contains a value and either two other trees or pointers to them.

The structure of the binary tree looks something like the following:

```
typedef struct T
{
   struct T *l;
   struct T *r;
   int v;
}T;
```

If using a list representation for a binary tree, it may look something like the following:

```
[root_value, left_node, right_node]
```

Comment: I mostly like your binary tree questions, but it would be nice if your definition was more inclusive of languages without the concept of pointers. Something like 'input will be a tree where a tree is either something containing a number and two other trees, or else something representing nothing. A tree must not be ambiguous'. This would include strings like `[5[][7[6[][]][8[][]]]`, where a tree is `[number tree tree]` or `[]` as well as the usual standard binary tree structures and lists

Answer (score 2):

## BotNets KotH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

> **Controller, Example and Submission Template now added**

---

*flavor text not yet written*

This is a web-based JS KotH where submissions have 2 parts, a Worker Bot and a Controller Bot. The goal is to have the most gold at the end of the game, by killing other bots and collecting gold found on the grid, while navigating the grid and surviving.

## Worker Bots

A Worker Bot is a class(ES6 or ES5) based on this format:

```
class YourWorkerBot extends WorkerBot {
    performAction(message) {}
    sendMessage(x, y, surroundings) {}
}
```

Each botnet has 20 Worker Bots. For every botnet, its worker bots are

#### Method Descriptions:

- `constructor(index)`: sets the color that the controller displays the bot as
- `performAction(message)`: returns an action(described below).
- `sendMessage(x,y,surroundings)`: `x` and `y` are zero-indexed coordinates. `surroundings` is a flat array of the 5x5 area around the bot. returns message(string) to send to controller bot

#### Actions

Each move is formatted as a 2 element list(`[action, param]`) where `action` is a string

- **Movement**: formatted as `["move", square]` where `square` is an integer that represents the square you want to move to, using the same index as the `surroundings` object. You can only move one square orthogonally or diagonally. Moving onto a square with a coin will collect the coin.
- **Kill**: formatted as `["kill", square]` where `square` is an integer that represents the square you want to attack, using the same index as the `surroundings` object. You can only kill a bot one square orthogonally or diagonally. If you kill a square with no bot, you do nothing. You get half the coins(rounded down) of the bot you attacked.
- **EMP**: formatted as `["emp",undefined]`. It causes all bots including itself in the 7x7 surrounding area can't move next turn. This costs 3 coins.
- Any invalid action is treated as you doing nothing.

#### Surroundings

The `surroundings` object will be a flat array of the 5x5 area around you, starting from the top left corner and going left to right and top to bottom. The grid below shows how the indexes of the array map to the actual grid area. Each square will be either a string, where "B" is a bot, "C" is a coin, "E" is an edge(not a valid move target) and "" is empty.

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

## Controller Bot

A Controller Bot is a class(ES6 or ES5) that extends the following class:

```
class YourControllerBot extends ControllerBot{
    constructor(locations){
         super(locations)    
         this.storage=""
    }
    sendMessage(messages,index){
         return ""
    }
}
```

Each botnet has only 1 Controller Bot.

#### Method Descriptions

- `constructor(locations)`: `locations` is an array of the initial locations([x,y]) of the worker bots.sets initial storage value
- `sendMessage(messages,index)`: `messages` is a list of lists of the messages sent by all the worker bots(not just your own), always in the same order and grouped by botnet. returns message to its worker bots whose index is `index`.

## The Game

The arena will be a 100x100 grid with 100 random coins scattered around it. Each game will have 1000 rounds and will have up to 15 randomly selected botnets. Every round, 10 coins will spawn at a random unoccupied spot. Every worker bot will get 1 turn per round. Each botnet's worker bots will perform an action in the same order for the entire game, but the order in which botnets take turns is randomized every round. Every turn, all the worker bots' `sendMessage` methods will be called(not just the worker bot taking the turn). After that, the controller bot's `sendMessage` method will be called. Finally, the worker bot's `performAction` method will be called and the action will be executed. This will repeat for every worker bot in a round.

## Scoring

Each botnet's score is the sum of the coins collected by each of the worker bots. Botnets are ranked by most score.

## Controller(WIP)

https://botnets-koth.firebaseapp.com

## Example

````
function sampleBotnet() {
    class SampleControllerBot extends ControllerBot {
        constructor(locations) {
            super(locations);
            this.storage = "";
        }
        sendMessage(messages, index) {
            let surrondings = messages.find(message => message[0] === index)[1];
            let otherBot = surrondings.findIndex(
                (square, i) =>
                    square === "B" && [6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18].includes(i)
            );
            if (otherBot !== -1) {
                return ["kill", otherBot];
            }
            let coin = surrondings.findIndex(
                (square, i) =>
                    square === "C" && [6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18].includes(i)
            );
            if (coin !== -1) {
                return ["move", coin];
            }
            let validMoves = [6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18].filter(
                x => surrondings[x] === ""
            );
            return [
                "move",
                validMoves[Math.floor(Math.random() * validMoves.length)]
            ];
        }
    }
    class SampleWorkerBot extends WorkerBot {
        performAction(message) {
            return message;
        }
        sendMessage(x, y, surroundings) {
            return [this.index, surroundings];
        }
    }
    return {
        name: "SampleBotnet",
        color: "red",
        controllerBot: SampleControllerBot,
        workerBot: SampleWorkerBot
    };
}

#Submission Template
```javascript
/* eslint constructor-super:0,no-this-before-super:0,no-unused-vars:0*/
import ControllerBot from "./src/scripts/ControllerBot.js";
import WorkerBot from "./src/scripts/WorkerBot.js";

//copy the part below
function yourBotnet() {
    class YourControllerBot extends ControllerBot {
        constructor(locations) {
            super(locations);
            this.storage = "";
        }
        sendMessage(messages, index) {
            return [];
        }
    }
    class YourWorkerBot extends WorkerBot {
        performAction(message) {}
        sendMessage(x, y, surroundings) {}
    }
    return {
        name: "YourBotnet",
        color: "",
        controllerBot: YourControllerBot,
        workerBot: YourWorkerBot
    };
}
````

## Rules

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- Bots cannot modify or add global variables
- Bots cannot call controller functions or other bots' methods
- Bots cannot read or modify other bots storage
- Bots may not access the internet
- I may disqualify any bot which does anything I deem to be cheating.

## Sandbox

- Is the bar to entry too high?
- Can the current turn/round system be improved?
- Any better names for the 2 bots/title?
- Is there enough room for creativity?
- Would it be better if I merged the 2 classes into one class?
- Is there anything broken with the spec?

Comment: How many workers per controller, and how many controllers per game? Also, are controllers supposed to be able to message to *all* workers, or just their own?

Comment: @UnrelatedString should be fixed

Comment: `performAction(surroundings, message) { return eval(message); }`
`sendMessage(surroundings) { return JSON.stringify(surroundings); }`
There are, of course, countless other ways to circumvent the size restrictions. I also find said restrictions quite brutal. Additionally, I don't see the point of worker-side storage. Finally, the whole document is difficult to read - giving a short summary of the goal at the beginning would go a long way.
*Nitpick: it's "surroundings", not "surrondings".*

Comment: Since your latest revision is "fixed spec": a) The `WorkerBot` class is invalid - calling `super` there is a syntax error. Do you want to show the base class that should be extended, or a template of how to extend said class? The second option makes more sense in my opinion, although the text right above seems to indicate otherwise. b.1) Under "Controller Bot", what is `index`? How is it chosen? b.2) What do bots that don't have the specified `index` receive as the message? b.3) Are there duplicate worker bot indexes possible? If not, please fix `sendMessages` descripiton.

Comment: c) Under 'The Game', `sendMessages` instead of `sendMessage` for controller bot. d) I'm worried about the split between worker bot and controller bot. I don't see how it would be anything but a minor nuisance under the current rules. Previously it was code-golf, but that's gone now. I'm also aware that it is supposed to be the essence of this challenge, so I'm hoping there's just a big misunderstanding somewhere. Perhaps it'll become clear once (b) is addressed.

Comment: I really like this idea! I think the combat could be improved (`kill` seems like it would just give too much power to the bots that go first in a turn), but the EMP is really creative (you might want to reduce it's range to what a worker can see, to reduce unintentional friendly fire). So that you don't need to order based on randomness, you can use a sort of "two pass" system where you first create a list of all the moves workers make, then apply them in a way that doesn't give any advantage to the worker who goes first (continued)

Comment: (continuation) For example, all EMPs would be applied, then all kills, then all movement. If two bots attempted to move into the same spot or kill each other, you could base it off of some secondary factor like number of coins/gold or most friendly workers in the vicinity. Good luck with the challenge, it seems really cool!

Answer (score 2):

## A Picture is Worth a Thousand Words

The average word is four characters/bytes long. So a picture, according to the old saying, is worth 4 kilobytes. But how complicated can that picture get?

Using any language or length of code you want, generate an image exactly 4,000 bytes in size with the highest possible entropy. You may use any standard image format. Your score will be the compression ratio when your image is compressed as a .zip file. For example, an image that compresses to 2,000 bytes will score 2, but if it expands to 4,100 bytes it will score 0.9756. Lowest score wins.

Comment: What image formats are allowed?

Comment: @wastl All of them.

Comment: should the program output to a file or can it print a list of bytes?

Comment: Interesting challenge. .zip is a file format, not a compression method, though. You'll need to specify what compression method is used -- DEFLATE, LZMA, etc. -- because that could drastically affect the scoring.

Comment: @SuperStormer It shouldn't matter as long as you upload the image file.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork How about gzip? I would specify version 1.6 because that's what I have.

Comment: If you say something like `gzip 1.6 using DEFLATE with default settings` that should probably suffice.

Comment: I didn't test this but I feel that any uncommon image format of raw data will have the optimal score (assume the compressor is smart enough to store without compression)

Answer (score 2):

## [caN it be acrOnymised?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190412/can-it-be-acronymised)

Comment: I shall hereby refer to Code Golf and Coding Challenges as DANGLE

Comment: Can the acronym contain lowercase letters? (For an example of that, see BSoD.)

Comment: @A__ While actual acronyms can, I'm going to say that the acronym will always be in complete uppercase, for simplicity's sake. And I've added in constraints on the length of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

### Up side down keyboard

Jono 2906 wants you to create a translator from plain Australian to up-side-down text after inventing a keyboard dedicated to typing up-side-down text, since they still want to demonstrate that their keyboard is powerful after failing to program in their keyboard.

However, they want your implementation to be typed with their own keyboard, since they also want to get used to programming using their keyboard.

### Input/Output

The whole ASCII character set mapped to their up-side down variation (the up-side down `"` is a double `,`):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~

 ¡,,#$%⅋,)(*+'-˙/
0ƖᄅƐㄣϛ9ㄥ86:;>=<¿
@∀qƆpƎℲפHIſʞ˥WNO
ԀQɹS┴∩ΛMX⅄Z]\[^‾
,ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞlɯuo
dbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz}|{~
```

The rest of the characters are kept as-is(yes, the unprintable characters are in the ASCII character set). The characters that are larger than 0x7f will be mapped back by subtracting the character code by 128.

If you are using a character that is larger than 256, modulo the character's character code by 128 before checking the availability.

### Rules

- No standard loopholes, please.
- Input and output will be taken with our standard input methods.
- If you force Jono 2906 to change a key on their keyboard (allowing typing your specified character), you will get a penalty of +2 bytes for every key you add.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)
[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: I don't think I quite follow. Are we given a character as input and need to output the upside-down version?

Comment: (1) I still find the question confusing even as to the basic functionality required. The "Input/Output" section seems to me to say that it's a Kolmogorov problem, but the "Rules" section talks about input. (2) If a character remapping is involved, the question should list Unicode codepoints for the characters in question, and should list test cases with Unicode codepoints. (3) Is the last rule saying that the program must work as is *and* after mangling? Or is it just a gimmick ("Post your code upside down, but it only has to work the right way up")?

Comment: "_The rest of the characters are **not** kept as-is(yes, the unprintable characters in the ASCII character set)._" should this _not_ be there? As for that entire paragraph, if I understand correctly: unprintable characters < 33 (as well as 127) will be kept as is; printable ASCII characters displayed will be converted to upside down; other printable ASCII characters and any character above 127 will be modulo-128 before doing the same check.

Comment: As for the last rule: we can only use those upside down characters in our source code, and when converting it to regular it should also work? So both programs `ABC` and `∀qƆ` should work exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

### Wrong position

I typr re;atively accuratrly, but so,etimes I made a whole nlock of text illegible by shifting a key right. So I need a program that corrects my text back to its original meaning.

### Rules

- You have to *left* shift on a standard English QWERTY keyboard.
- Whitespace do not count for the procedure before left-shifting and are kept as-is in a standard left-shifting procedure. If the key is the leftmost letter/symbol on a keyboard(i.e. `The ~key, Q key, A key, Z key.`), the key is kept as-is. If you reach a control character while left-shifting (`Caps lock and Shift`), their effects will not be triggered and the character before left-shifting is kept.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer wins.
- Both the input and the output shall be given via our [default methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

### Representation of a subset of the QWERTY keyboard that you will need

The two lines connected are possible values of the key: shifted/unshifted.

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+
`1234567890-=

QWERTYUIOP{}|
qwertyuiop[]\

ASDFGHJKL:"
asdfghjkl;'

ZXCVBNM<>?
zxcvbnm,./

(Space)
(Space)
```

### Input

The input will always be a non-empty string conforming the rules above.

### Output

The output will be the input string corrected to the originally intended meaning.

### Examples:

```
Yjod ,sfr yjr, imjsppu/ -> This made them unhappy.
vpfr hp;g -> code golf
```

### Feedback

I think this is *not* a duplicate; however, is any part of this challenge unclear or needs improvements?

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: I think you are mixing up left and right. Clearly, `~`, `Q`, `A` and `Z` are leftmost keys, NOT rightmost. And your examples appear to be left-shifting, not right-shifting.

Comment: "*I think this is a duplicate*" - so why sandbox it? Or did a *not* go missing in editing?

Comment: Thank you. Predominantly my mouse was not working again, I didn't get around to fix this.

Comment: "sonetimes" and "vlock" are shifted the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

## Path to Path Rearrangement

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal)

In the xkcd comic ["Map of the Internet"](https://xkcd.com/195/), a special fractal path was used, similar to this:

```
0  1  14 15
3  2  13 12
4  7  8  11
5  6  9  10
```

Ascii art version:

```
-0---1  14---15--16 19--20---21
     |   |       |   |       |
 3---2  13---12 17---18 23---22
 |           |           |
 4   7---8   11 30---29 24---25
 |   |   |   |   |   |       |
 5---6   9---10 31  28--27---26
                 |
58---57 54---53 32  35--36---37
 |   |   |   |   |   |       |
59  56---55  52 33---34 39---38
 |           |           |
60---61 50---51 46---45 40---41
     |   |       |   |       |
63---62 49---+---47 44--43---42
\|/
```

This path, known as the [Hilbert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100335/draw-the-hilbert-curve) [curve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104392/ascii-hilbert-curve), has some interesting properties. Among other things, it can be flipped diagonally without changing most of those properties.

```
-0   3---4---5  58--59---60  63->
 |   |       |   |       |   |
 1---2   7---6  57---56 61---62
         |           | 
14---13  8---9  54---55 50---49
 |   |       |   |       |   |
15  12--11---10 53--52---51   48
 |                           |
16---17 30---31--32--33 46---47
     |   |           |   |
19---18 29---28 35---34 45---44
 |           |   |           |
20  23---24  27 36  39---40  43
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
21---22 25---26 37---38 41---42
```

Your task is to apply this transformation. Given a space on one path, find the corresponding location on the other. For example, the fourth space in the top path is located at (0, 2), which is the 14th space along the second path, so the correct output for 4 is 14.

As with similar [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, this can be done as:

- An infinite sequence along the second path of the corresponding locations along the first path
- A function/program that takes a numbered position on the first path and returns the distance to that point on the second path.
- A function/program that takes a numbered position on the first path and returns all path 1 positions along path 2 to the point specified.

The first 64 terms of this sequence (zero indexed, add one to each for one indexed) are:

```
0 3 2 1 14 15 12 13 8 11 10 9 6 7 4 5 58 57 56 59 60 63 62 61 50 49 48 51 52 55 54 53 32 35 34 33 46 47 44 45 40 43 42 41 38 39 36 37 26 25 24 27 28 31 30 29 18 17 16 19 20 23 22 21
```

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

> ### Meta Questions
>
> - Do I need a better description of the paths?
> - Is the challenge itself clear?
> - Any other issues I should fix before posting?

Comment: The default output formats for [tag:sequence] challenges can be found in the [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)

Comment: (1) [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100335/194). (2) I don't find "*Find the location along the second path of a point on the first path*" at all clear. It seems to be talking about output in 2D. I think it would be clearer to say "Given an index on the first path, output the index of the same coordinate on the second path". And then give a worked example (e.g. 4 vs 14).

Answer (score 2):

## **Is this number part of a Collatz prime sequence?**

A fast step of the Collatz sequence is defined as

$$s_\mathrm{Collatz}:\mathbb{N}_\mathrm{odd}\to\mathbb{N},\quad n \mapsto \frac{3\cdot n+1}{2}.$$

Given an odd positive integer \$n\in\mathbb{N}_\mathrm{odd}\$, your task is to decide whether or not both \$n\$ and \$s_\mathrm{Collatz}(n)\$ are prime numbers.

Your program should output two distinct and unique values to represent truthiness and falseness, whereby falseness may also be represented by signalling an error.

Since \$n+\frac12(n+1)=n+\lceil\frac n2\rceil\$ for odd \$n\$, the sorted sequence of all numbers which result in truthiness in the above sense is equal to the tail of [A158709](https://oeis.org/A158709).

### Test cases

```
-8 -> -        ; undefined behavior
1  -> false    ; (3*1 +1)/2 = 4 is not prime
3  -> true     ; (3*3 +1)/2 = 5 is prime
5  -> false    ; (3*5 +1)/2 = 8 is not prime
7  -> true     ; (3*7 +1)/2 = 11 is prime
11 -> true     ; (3*11+1)/2 = 17 is prime
15 -> false    ; 15 is not prime
91 -> false    ; (3*91+1)/2 = 137 is prime, yet 91 is not
97 -> false    ; (3*97+1)/2 = 146 is not prime
```

Comment: What is the definition defining? Is \$p\$ a Collatz prime iff it's a prime and \$\frac{3p+1}2\$ is a prime? If \$p\$ a Collatz prime iff it's a prime and \$\frac{2p-1}3\$ is a prime? Or is a prime Collatz if either of those conditions hold?

Comment: @PeterTaylor are they not the same thing?

Comment: Alternative phrasing: which of \$p_1\$ and \$p_2\$ are you calling a Collatz prime?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean \$p_1\$

Comment: So neither the input prime nor the Collatz prime need to be prime?

Comment: "Input MAY be non-prime, in which case the output is always false (see 15)" -- did you specifically define this behavior or why is the above the case?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I'm (personally) only interested in going from prime to prime, but I wanted to define the haviour for non-prime input. When I say 'may be non-prime' I mean, it should be able to handle it, it's an allowed/expected input but not one that gives a True output.

Comment: To me it feels like an unnatural extra constraint.

Comment: @JonathanFrech it's just defining how to behave with certain inputs.

Comment: Citing [Exceptional edge cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17611/73111); such out-of-place definitions are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I've changed the initial ask, and now it shouldn't be an exception

Comment: Cf. [A158709](https://oeis.org/A158709).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Do you think this is postable?

Comment: @Pureferret Since you specifically asked me, I made an admittedly large edit, trying to unambiguously defined your task. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: Should `91` result in truthiness or falseness?

Comment: cf. Things to avoid when writing challenges: [Prime numbers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/78410). Unless there's a mathematical way to avoid any of the existing golfed primality test methods, a task involving primality test is not very interesting.

Comment: I agree with @Bubbler; especially testing for \$n\$ to be prime. Although I doubt testing \$s_\mathrm{Collatz}(n)\$ for primality is golfable.

Comment: @Pureferret I would not post it -- unless you can think of an interesting golf opportunity. You could, however, improve the problem at hand: there are many questions one can ask about Collatz trajectories. And if you ask for something along the lines of "decide if the given number is a multiple of the length of its Collatz trajectory", you get a less arbitrary connection of concepts whilst preserving the topic of divisibility.

Answer (score 2):

## Creep Spread Territorial Control (WIP)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (probably)

---

Blah blah blah flavor blah blah blah something about Starcraft blah blah blah

## Gameplay

### Initial State

There is a 150x150 grid of square cells with approximately 7500 random cells missing in a symmetric Perlin noise pattern. There are four creep spread factions competing for dominance of this territory beginning as a single cell 10 cells in from a corner of the grid (one faction per corner). Each faction starts with 50 energy. The board *does not* wrap around at the edges.

### Expansion

Each turn, each faction earns 1 point of energy for each controlled cell plus 20 base energy. This energy is used for expansion. How much a cell costs to expand to depends on how many cells controlled by the same faction are in the [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) of the target cell.

- 0 neighbors: cannot expand to this cell
- 1 neighbor: 50 energy
- 2 neighbors: 20 energy
- 3 neighbors: 12 energy
- 4 neighbors: 8 energy
- 5 neighbors: 5 energy
- 6 neighbors: 3 energy
- 7 neighbors: 2 energy
- 8 neighbors: 1 energy

There is no limit to how many cells can be expanded to in one turn other than energy costs. All expansions occur simultaneously. If two or more factions attempt to claim the same cell on the same turn, the one with the most neighbors of its own faction will claim the cell. If there is a tie, none of the factions claim that cell. Players whose expansions failed due to competition will not be refunded. Factions may expand onto each other's territory, stealing ownership of the cell.

### Game End

The game lasts 10,000 turns or until there is only one faction remaining, whichever happens first. The winner is the faction with the most owned cells. Ties are broken by remaining energy.

The overall winner will be resolved with a randomized pool where each bot plays an equal number of games followed by 12 games of the top 4 contenders. (one for each possible corner positioning)

## Coding

Write a bot that plays this game

- Bots must be deterministic. As a way to provide localized pseudorandomness, a random integer between \$0\$ and \$2^{32}-1\$ will be passed to the bot, which will be seedable in the controller.
- Bots have perfect information of the current state of the board, which turn it is, and their own energy, but not the energy of other players.
- Bots may not remember anything between turns, but may initialize constants and utility functions at the beginning of each game.

The list of desired expansions is ordered. As soon as an invalid expansion target cell is encountered (whether by cost or lack of same-faction neighbors) in this list, the *rest of the list will be ignored* and a warning will be logged.

Comment: So if I build at `0,1` and `1,0` on the same turn while having a cell at `0,0`, the cost would be 2000, yeah? Are failed expansions refunded? Also, I think having a source of randomness would be good.

Comment: @Veskah, that would cost 2000, correct. I'll add some rules about when failed expansions are refunded.

Comment: Suggestions: **1.** Maybe allow expanding to own territory too? Could be used as a defensive mechanism when you can predict that you are going to be attacked. (should be thought about, could be bad) **2.** Maybe set a limit on how many cell expansions can happen per turn to avoid exponentially expansion? I'm thinking that a bot which gains some advantage might get unstoppable when it is unlimited.

Comment: **3.** More clarification in rules about expansions, for example if player 1 and 2 have a tie on this turn for cell X and they both go for it, but player 1 also goes for a neighbor of cell X in same turn, will player 1 win? (@Veskah mentioned another scenario too) **4.** I would suggest using JavaScript so more people can write and run the code (anyone with a browser can do it), also a controller with some helper functions could be nice, for example a function which returns expansion cost for a cell in an optimized way to avoid tens of different implementations for same common action.

Comment: **5.** *"Bots have perfect information of the current state of the board."*, does this include current energy value of other players?

Comment: @Night2 **1** Interesting. It seems a bit fiddly. **2** This *should* actually come out to a quadratic expansion rate since where you can expand to is derived from perimeter, which grows linearly. **3** All expansions are resolved simultaneously (as in Conway's Game of Life), so player 1 does not win that tie. **4** Javascript is the likely plan since I intend to have a significant graphical component. **5** I'll have to think about it. That could be rather interesting as 'private' information.

Comment: **6.** Proposal to spice things up: board is randomly generated, with some cells being unavailable for expansion. Uniform random, Perlin/Simplex noise, [cellular automaton-based cave generation](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generate-random-cave-levels-using-cellular-automata--gamedev-9664), etc. **7.** Will the bots have access to the turn counter? **8.** Maybe rotate and/or mirror the board provided to the bots so that each bot starts at, for example, the top-left corner from its perspective?

Comment: **9.** Allow bots to pre-calculate some data on load or game start. This will allow people to speed up their bots. Especially useful if you end up implementing **6**.

Comment: @Alion **6** That sounds pretty interesting. I'll probably expand the board slightly in that case. **7** Yes, they'll know what turn it is. **8** I don't think that adds much. I'm probably going to have to make copies of the board every turn anyway to make it impossible to cheat on accident though... **9** Seems reasonable.

Comment: *"Bots must be deterministic. As a way to provide localized pseudorandomness, a random integer ... will be passed to the bot, which will be seedable in the controller."*. Why not make a custom random function available or override the default random generator and make the controller generate and handle the seeds? For example in JavaScript users can still use the normal `Math.random()`, but you can use this to make it deterministic: http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html

Comment: @Night2, yeah. I'll probably do that since I'm going to have to use an RNG library anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## The Celestial Bureaucracy [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193234/the-celestial-bureacracy-koth)

Comment: This sounds like a lot of fun. When the exam is asked, is it possible to know which bot gave the exam?

Comment: You are given the ID of the bot via the parameter for `ask`, which allows you to identify if you've interacted with that bot before and if it's the Jade Emperor (because his ID is always -1). You won't get the name - if you want to identify the bot, you'll have to analyse its question and answer pattern.

Answer (score 2):

## [Calculate the Ultraradical](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193376/calculate-the-ultraradical) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: I'd recommend removing the text with a strikethrough; I think it is just confusing. "Accurate to 6 significant digits" isn't a very good validity criterion since it would require testing each and every possible input the program could handle. I'd recommend saying it has to be that accurate for your test cases but not be hardcoded for them, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

### Maximize the Hello, world's in code permutations

In this task you should output this exact string: `hi orb` (because Earth is a sphere). However, here is the catch: you must output as many `hi orb`'s as possible in all of your code permutations. Identical permutations do not count(e.g. `aa`'s permutations count as one permutation)

Say you have a program `abc` that outputs this string. You should try your best to make `acb`, `bac`, `bca`, `cab`, and `cba` (i.e. the permutations of `abc`) also output this exact string.

### Rules

- No standard loopholes, please.
- Input/output must obey our standard methods.
- Your score is simply the factorial of the length of your code. **You shall also present the following score:** The score is counted in the negative of the length of your source code **divided by** the number of permutations that your code generates; (expression: `-(source length/permutations)`.) Of course you want to keep your score as low as possible.
- All comment characters in your language are disallowed, in order to avoid collapsing into a radiation-hardening challenge.
- If you are using the filename as data, the filename must also count in the permutations.
- The source code length should be <1000. (Don't ask why, it's just an attempt of avoiding abusing the source code length.)

### Feedback

- Is it detailed enough?
- Is the input/output rules clear enough?
- Do I need any more information?

I don't think this is a duplicate because nobody has asked a question tagged with both permutation and hello-world. However, I worry that this challenge will collapse into a radiation-hardening challenge if you comment out a single character and then make sure that this will produce the same result, therefore making it a flavored version of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/fault-tolerant-hello-world-a-k-a-the-interview) and close to a duplicate.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)[hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

Comment: Can't you just extend your score by increasing your byte counnt, as long as you have some commented out part or no-op?

Comment: `Unneccecary NOPs are disallowed, and at least 1 permutation of your code must only contain relevant code and nops.` is rather vague, since no-ops aren't really defined, nor is this challenge really that possible to increase score if you don't have no-ops, otherwise it will turn into a duplicate of the normal Hello World question

Comment: This reminds me of [a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16735/76162) I sandboxed a while ago, but deleted since it was clear it would produce only trivial answers

Comment: [tag:code-golf] scoring usually has lowest score (=code length) wins. If you break with that convention, you should mention it in the rules.
I think a big problem with this is that for any non-trivial answer (Like `H` in HQ9+), the proof of correctness of the score is almost impossible, because unlike radiation-hardening, the amount of variants increases factorially instead of linearly with the code length.

Comment: Hmm, it is okay, I will make the score negative then. I believe a program running the permutations of a string (not counting repeated ones) and evaluating them to check the result will be sufficient. Hmm, that's why the submittor needs to golf their code: to allow others to check their answers.

Comment: That's where it's unfeasible: The highest-scoring answer in the challenge you linked has 96 bytes. That's 9.9*10^149 permutations to check if they output the correct result. Even assuming your implementation is the fastest possible, that would take years, just for that single answer. You can't brute-force determine the score, but using mathematical trickery to try and calculate the score by hand will be arduous and prone to errors.

Comment: I don't think the limitations you have put are going to prevent this from falling apart. For example, [this Pyth program](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XykjNSdfoTy/KEVJQSkxKTktPTMrOzevoLC4pLSsorJKT0/v/38A) works for any permutation of the code where only characters after the third `"` are permuted. Completely filling up the code allowed will achieve a score exceedingly close to zero. I don't think that is what you want, but I'm not really sure you can fix it (like what happened to Jo King), sorry.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman this particular snippet fails the rule that all code needs to be relevant. However, even if we tighten the rule to all code being life and necessary, that is, in one permutation, all code is executed, and a deletion of any statement resulting in the code not outputting "Hello World" any more, you can still cheese the challenge by bloating the code.
The only way to stop that would be to change the scoring method to also use the factorial of the byte count, but then A) HQ9+ is unbeatable and B) It's a math challenge because you have to calculate the amount of viable permutations

Comment: Instead of `helo word`, wouldn't it make more sense to just use a different phrase like `greeting earthlings` or something along those lines? I agree with @AdmBorkBork that `helo` just looks weird. I do think it shouldn't be `hello world` to prevent builtins, so `helo word` is already better, but it still looks weird and will raise questions for sure..

Comment: I don't understand the scoring. If we're scored only on the factorial of the length of code, why does it matter how many permutations output `hi orb`? I would figure that the number of ways that is output should factor into the scoring somehow...

Answer (score 2):

I came across this little web game [Drench](http://flashbynight.com/drench/)
Its a fairly mindless game , I wrote a small JS snippet to play this game for me in the background of my browser, it cycles through and clicks on the 6 possible moves

```
let ind =0;
let games =0;
let wins =0;
let lastMoves = "";
setInterval(function(){
  if (jQuery('.moveNum').text() != lastMoves) {
    lastMoves = jQuery('.moveNum').text();
    ind++;
    ind = ind%6;
    jQuery('.pbutton:nth('+ind+')').click();
  } else {
    games++;
    if ((jQuery('.moveNum').text()*1)) {wins++;}
    jQuery('#myCanvas').click();
  }
},200);
```

This Strategy wins about 3% of the time
My question is, is there a more optimal strategy that will allow me to win a greater % of the time (without looking at the board)?

Comment: Hi and thanks for using the sandbox! Though this is a bit unusual for this site, I think your question is on-topic, just far too broad. "Can I do better" just isn't something you can really ask on the SE network. I think the best way for you to move forward is to fully explain the game in the body of your post, and then score submissions based on their win percentage.

Comment: I really like the idea though - I think win% is the way to go

Comment: Make this a code-challenge? To verify, you can run it for, for example, 500 times and calculate the winning percent?

Comment: Coded this up in p5.js, you can play it here https://hoppingmad9.github.io/dench/
Happy to convert it to pure js if needed and could add an interface to get the board state and input moves.

Comment: oops, well I guess the code golf version can be called "Dench" not "Drench". I thought "Dench" was a weird name

Comment: Probably needs a time limit for each turn to prevent people trying every single possibility of moves

Answer (score 2):

## Turing-complete regex subset

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

[It's widely known](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/55934) that a programming language is one iff it's capable of addition of natural numbers and primality testing. In practice, this criterion has a high accuracy for distinguishing Turing-complete languages too.<sup>[[citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)]</sup>

### Cops' challenge

Choose any of the programming languages available on [tio.run](https://tio.run/). Write a regex that will define a subset of this programming language. The subset must still match the definition, though ideally this should be far from obvious.

Write two programs in this language that match this regex:

1. Take two natural numbers, `a` and `b`, as input. Output `a + b`. The program must work for `0 ≤ a + b < 215`.
2. Take a natural number `n` as input. Output whether the number is prime. The program must work for `0 ≤ n < 215`.

The behavior outside of this range is undefined. This means that you can output the correct answer, a cute cat ASCII art, an error, an invalid answer, invoke nasal demons, or anything else you can, or cannot, imagine.

Regex come in multiple flavors. Choose one. You can choose any flavor available on [regex101](https://regex101.com/), or [Retina](https://tio.run/#retina1).

In your answer, include:

- the programming language and regex flavor you chose
- the regex delimiter and flags you chose (for example: `//gm`; does not apply to Retina)
- the regex you wrote and its byte count
- the byte counts of your two programs

**Keep the programs hidden.** If 7 days pass without anyone cracking your answer, you may reveal your two programs by editing them into your answer. This will make your answer safe. Your score then becomes **your regex's bytecount** (lower is better). Before your answer is safe, your score is positive infinity.

### Robbers' challenge

Write two programs that prove the subset to be a valid programming language. The rules that apply here are the same that apply to the cops. Additionally, your programs must not exceed the cops' in length.

When you crack an answer, post your programs to the [robbers' thread](https://doesnotexistyet.com).

> ## Meta questions
>
> The above will be posted as the cops' thread, with the robbers' thread simply linking to it.
>
> - Any improvements to challenge structure? I've never done this before.
> - Do you see any loopholes that need addressing?
> - Are the allowed regex flavors reasonable?
> - Duplicates?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread

Comment: @pppery Hmm. These are definitely pretty similar. On the other hand, regexes might allow more interesting answers.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a dupe since most of the interesting work here is in selecting the regex rather than in choosing a sequence, though  I think the other challenge is cleaner. I think the optimal scoring regex will usually be to make an "unhash" that produces the appropriate programs. Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions at the moment to help fix that, but if you can then I think this is alright.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I can't see what you mean by "unhash" here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Consider [this program](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X6/M2cjC2NTcwvD/f1MucwA) which performs the first task. The regex that matches only programs like this would be short but but not very informative. I think doing this but making guessing the magic number arbitrarily hard would usually be the best approach in a given language.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Like, `/^\.vC\d+$/`? I think that making it complicated enough would take quite a lot of bytes.

Comment: The point is that the number could be manipulated, so I could pad my program arbitrarily until I got a number that let me write a regex like `^...(2|10|76|345?)*$`. That's neither very long nor easy to crack.

Comment: I like the idea of the challenge but I feel including the bit about Turing completeness is a bit of a red herring, it only really distracts from the challenge.

Comment: To elaborate the particular part I like is regex selection part.  I do agree that my challenge is a bit cleaner otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

[Moved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194141/gerrymander-north-carolina).

Comment: For the tiebreak, what does code with the fewest bytes mean, given that we're outputting a county assignment?

Comment: @xnor - I modified the scoring mechanism to not require tie breaks. Thanks to this modification, I expect the code submissions to be much more interesting.

Comment: I like your new assignment score and no longer having a code golf tiebreak.The leave-one-out looks kind-of complicated and might take a long time to run-- is there a way to simplify it? The challenge looks a lot more intimidating that when I last commented, though the idea looks the same. I guess you want to make sure people actually write code that kind-of generalizes rather than possible finding an assignment by hand. Maybe also consider something with the standard deviation in assignment place of the max-min ratio so there's also an incentive to try to balance populations in the middle?

Comment: @xnor - Great points, thanks! I simplified things by cutting the number of leave-one-out instances by a factor of 10. (I selected these 10 counties based on political geography considerations.) I also toned down the math speak to make the challenge less intimidating. I thought about standard deviation instead of max-min, but max-min is closer to how we enforce one person, one vote in practice.

Answer (score 2):

## Create a safe crossing.

---

Given a string/number/array of any two distinct characters make the "squarest" 2D array that allows "someone" to cross from left to right or top to bottom "stepping" only on whichever character you have chosen as your stepping stone

#### or

Make the "squarest" array possible that contains a complete row or column of stepping stone characters. (clearer but takes away the fun story-ness)

---

"squarest" meaning smallest difference between the dimensions of the 2D array.

### Input

- A string/number/array of your choosing consisting only of your two chosen distinct characters. So no error checking needed. Allow true/false values if input is array?
- input will have at least 1 stepping stone character so that a valid solution is always possible 1 by x or x by 1
- a minimum length of x? needed? might make it easier if there's some weirdness with very short arrays in the algorithms people come up with
- the last row can be incomplete to allow for prime number length inputs and to more easily allow non trivial 1xX/Xx1 answers

### Output

The output should be the dimensions of the array

- and specify the row or column to use?
- print your 2D array so that the path can be seen graphically?

### Test Cases

100100100 -> 3x3 array

```
100
100
100
```

11111000 -> 4x2 or 3x3 - 3x3 is squarer so is correct

```
1111    111
1000    110
        00
```

11000011000101001001 -> 5x4

```
11000
01100
01010
01001
```

1000000000000 -> 12x1 - trivial as only 1 stepping stone

```
100000000000
```

010111 -> 3x2 or 2x3 - either acceptable as both are only "1" away from square

```
010    01
111    01
       11
```

### This is code-golf so the shortest code in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

### Issues

- allow diagonal crossings? does that make it a lot harder?
- need a lot more test cases I think?
- input spec
- output spec
- better/more tags?

Answer (score 2):

## ASCII Sum of your code

Encoding is nice, adding things is also nice. Let's do *both* !

Your task will be to create a program that read itself, convert every of its character into ASCII values and return the sum of those numbers.

### Example

Let's say your program is `Hello, world !`. Convert every character into ascii values

```
H  e   l   l   o   ,  (space) w   o   r   l   d   (space) !
72 101 108 108 111 44 32      119 111 114 108 100 32      33
```

Now, sum everything into a <s>meaningless</s> very useful value

```
72 + 101 + 108 + 108 + 111 + 44 + 32 + 119 + 111 + 114 + 108 + 100 + 32 + 33
= 1193
```

Here it is, `Hello, world!` returns `1193` !

### Rules

- The code have to **read itself** and **calculate** the result
- Standard loopholes are **not** allowed
- This is codegolf, so the fewer bytes wins.
- Non-standard languages with non-ASCII characters should use their own codepage's encodings (Thanks for @Veskah for this rule)

---

## Feedback

- Is the challenge clear enouth ?
- Is there an already existing challenge like this one ?
- is this considered as a duplicate of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/write-a-program-to-print-the-sum-of-the-ascii-codes-of-the-program) ?

Comment: I would probably have non-standard languages use their codepage's encodings (pretty much all of them should be 8 bytes) to crunch their output. The big hammer approach would be to ban non-ASCII languages but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Requiting the code to read itself and do the calculation is a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20260). Since it seems you don't want programs that just hardcode the value, I think the best way to be just to require the program take in an input string to use. Regardless, I don't really see room for interesting golfing in the challenge, since pretty much any normal-ish language has built-ins to take ASCII values and compute sums, and weird languages that don't have already done these as subtasks for many many challenges.

Comment: @xnor Does this challenge with string input already exist ?

Comment: I don't remember an exact one, but I'm finding very close ones: [averaging ASCII values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53675/20260) and [summing then counting binary 1's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94558/20260), which was closed as a duplicate of one without the character adding. I also found an [unrestricted quine challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135571/20260) with the same task as yours. So I think there's a good chance this would be closed as a duplicate either way.

Comment: Yup, the last one is quite the same as mine.
Duplicate it is then.

Answer (score 2):

## It's slashing time

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

*(Inspired by [Seven Slash Display](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51445/42963))*

You're lying in bed, awake. Sleepily, you turn your head to the alarm clock and read what time it is. Since you're lying down, the clock is facing diagonally, making it difficult to read. You decide to write a program to help you out (hey, you're awake anyway).

Given a "slashed" seven-segment display, output what time it is in 24-hour format.

```
      /\
       /\
    /\  /
    \ \
   . \/
 /\ .
  /
  \/

2:03
```

You can choose where to place the `:` between the numbers (for example, evenly spaced as above or left-aligned as below, etc.), but the `:` must be present.

Some further examples:

```
       \
        \
    /\
     /\
  / . /
  \/\.
 \  /
  \

15:31

       \
      \/\
     \
      \
   \.
    \.

1:14
```

Here are the precise digit shapes:

```
/\
\ \
 \/

 \
  \


/\
 /
 \/

/\
 /\
  /

 \
\/\

/
\/\
  /

/
\/\
 \/

/\
  \

/\
\/\
 \/

/\
\/\
  /
```

### Rules & Standard I/O boilerplate

- The time will always be valid. For example, you'll never receive something like `30:25` or `7:99` or the like.
- You're allowed to pad the input with whitespace however necessary (e.g., padding it to always be a rectangle with trailing spaces).

Comment: Input always a valid time? [Can we shift the dots?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XwEM9GO4FFBY@jFADGLpxSgARYBcvRgQX18BSABZXFyENCpANeopQDXqgXX@/w8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: `2` in `2:03` is not aligned with other digits :(

Comment: @tsh Indeed it wasn't. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

## Room volume as a function of paint on the walls/ceiling

**Task:** Write a function that will take in the size of a room (height, width, and length) and a number of paint layers (given that the layers are of a consistent thickness) and return the area of free space in the room after that many layers of paint are applied.

**Requirements:**

- Return the final area left in the room after the paint layers are added
- should be able to run on a room of any size
- The answer must account for the decreasing area in the room as each layer is applied.
- number of layers and paint layer thickness should both be inputs
- must account for walls and ceiling
- standard loopholes are disallowed

The winner is determined via byte count

Comment: How thick is each coat of paint? Also, do you mean return the volume of free space in the room?

Answer (score 2):

List of integers to pairs **?? Any suggestions for the title ??**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

Write a function or a full program taking a *list of non negative integers numbers* `L` that outputs a *pair* of numbers [`X , Y`] such that *X %( Y + i )  == L [ i ]*  .

**Output specifications**

- You can output `X Y` in any order, just indicate it and be consistent.
- `X Y` are also unsigned integers, obviously `Y` must be greater than `0` to avoid modulo 0 errors.
- If your language doesn't support 0 indexed list you can consider *X %( Y + i )  == L [ i **+ 1** ]*  **?? Any suggestions how to handle this ??**

**Example**

[ 1, 2, 3 ] => [ 11, 2 ]

```
 11 %( 2 + 0 ) = 1
 11 %( 2 + 1 ) = 2
 11 %( 2 + 2 ) = 3
```

[ 10, 2 ] => [ 98, 11 ]

```
 98 %( 11 + 0 ) = 10
 98 %( 11 + 1 ) = 2
```

---

## Test cases

[ input ] , [ output ] pairs

```
[ 0, 1, 2 ] ,  [ 5, 1 ]
[ 1, 2 ] ,  [ 5, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ] ,  [ 11, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ,  [ 59, 2 ]
[ 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ] ,  [ 9, 5 ]
[ 6, 12, 18 ] ,  [ 3318, 18 ]
[ 27, 18, 9 ] ,  [ 279, 28 ]
[ 3, 9, 27 ] ,  [ 4059, 26 ]
[ 2, 4, 8, 16 ] ,  [ 8584, 14 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ,  [ 60, 1 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ,  [ 61, 2 ]
[ 120, 20 ] ,  [ 12220, 121 ]
[ 10, 2 ] ,  [ 98, 11 ]
[ 9, 8, 7, 0 ] ,  [ 1339, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 4, 9, 2, 10, 4, 15, 10, 5, 0, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0, 22, 19, 16, 13 ] ,  [ 100, 10 ]
[ 9, 99, 90, 81, 72, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27 ] ,  [ 999, 99 ]
```

---

## Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

---

Comment: For the testcases I think you can omit the outer parenthesis and the trailing comma. Furthermore I'd talk about *nonnegative integers* instead of *unsigned integers*.

Comment: But I have another question: Is this problem always solvable?

Comment: @flawr thanks I'll fix then. For the second question Idk.. Numbers increase extremely, I made a program for solving the problem and also a program to do the reverse(X,Y to list) I may do some test for each X,Y to a certain number..

Comment: I don't think `[0,0,1,1]` has a solution (consider the parity of **X**) cc @flawr

Comment: @H.PWiz sadly yes

Comment: @flawr and H.PWiz so if it's not always solvable do I have to delete this challenge?

Comment: I dunno, you could guarantee that the input is solvable. Or you could ask a different (harder) question instead: "Is there a solution?"

Answer (score 2):

## Create a block maze solver AI

> A block maze is a maze in which goal is to complete a pathway by
>   adding blocks.

It starts like this :

```
#..#.
#...#
..###
.#...
.#..#
```

`#` is a block (which can be crossed). `.` is empty space (which cannot be crossed).

The goal is to connect top-left corner `S` to the bottom-right corner `E`. Diagonals are not allowed.

```
S....
.....
.....
.....
....E
```

One possible solution for the example above is to add three blocks like this :

```
#..#.
#...#
#####
.#..#
.#..#
```

Think about a man who want to cross a river with crocodiles `.` using huge stone blocks `#`.

The task is to create a program that take a grid as input and return a solution as output.

### Scoring

The sum of all blocks required to solve all solutions in a 1.000 test case file I will provide.

The winning program is the one that use the fewest blocks to solve all mazes.

### Rules

- All grids are 25 x 25.
- Start / end points are always top-left / bottom-right corners. There is always a block on those points.
- There is always one guaranteed solution (which can be found by filling all empty spaces)
- Program must be entirely deterministic; pseudorandom solutions are allowed, but the program must generate the same output for the same test case every time. If two programs take the same number of steps (e.g. they both found the optimal solutions), the shorter program will win.

The program should return the solution as a sequence of blocks x-y coordinates (the coordinates of blocks to add to solve maze) in the format of your choosing :

```
11-3;15-6;19-12
```

### Meta

- I cannot think of a simple algorithm that returns an optimal (best possible) solution in a reasonable time. I expect programs to use some heuristics to get non-optimal/near-optimal solutions. I made the grids 25 x 25 to make it challenging enough and prevent simple solutions like brute force.
- Is this a duplicate? There is lot of [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze) related questions but I couldn't find anything related to [block maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze#Other_types_of_mazes).
- The tags are [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)[path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding). Anything else?

---

EDIT : as **AlienAtSystem** pointed out in comments, there is an optimal algorithm for all cases. I made some tests: even a slightly modified Dijkstra's algorithm  will work (it will find shortest path in a short time). I will not post this challenge as it is trivial. I leave it here in case someone else would have same idea.

Comment: By fewest total steps, do you mean cumulatively?

Comment: I mean the sum of all blocks. If solution for `maze01` use 4 blocks and solution for `maze02` use 5 blocks, it is `4+5 = 9 blocks` in total. The lowest is the best. Someone who has `7+1=8 blocks` will win. I have edited answer.

Comment: You should allow people to have any output format as long as it has `x` first, `y` second. None of the `maze`s are duplicate. I can't think of any other tags. This should be good to post.

Comment: Should we add a test suite of some sort? Or how are you going to verify the score of a submission? But in general the challenge looks clear. A few questions: I assume there are some test cases among the 1000 requiring us to go right/up for the optimal solution, instead of only going left/down? Are the input-characters strict, or could we also use for example `012` for `@.x` respectively as integer-matrix? One other relevant tag: [[path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/path-finding/info)]

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I am planning to provide a program to validate solutions. right/up : some mazes might be shorter to solve that way but it is not allowed. The goal is go from top-left to bottom-right (not to cross from left to right). character set : programs should use the same characters as the test file. Anyway, using `012` might be a good idea (I might update the test file with such chars). There is no `@` character in the test file since the start / end position are always the same.

Comment: @tigrou Ah ok, so `@` is not part of the input. In that case a binary-matrix with just `0`s and `1`s would be a suitable input format I guess. As for the right/up: I meant it for an input like [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rWnM2GDb). With this maze you could walk from the top-left to bottom-right with just 2 `x` insertions (at the `_` positions), but you'd have to travel up and left in the path from the top-left to bottom-right. But if I understand correctly we only travel right and down, so [this would be the solution](https://pastebin.com/6i3NCUmW) (with 4 insertions at `_`) instead?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : both solutions you posted are valid. You can go up / down / left right at any moment.

Comment: I can think of an algorithm that should be optimal for all test cases. This could result in the [tie-breaker problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8195/89287) if other people realize it, too.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem : optimal algo : is it because of my test cases (which have some flaws) or the maze challenge in general ?

Comment: @tigrou In general. It can be translated into a shortest path challenge over a considerably smaller graph. While A* wouldn't work on that one, other algorithms will. This wouldn't be short in terms of bytes, although I suspect not that much compared to other approaches, given that some part tasks need to be done by everyone.

Comment: I think you don't need to give up entirely right away. While this doesn't work as test-battery challenge because it's too easy to get everything right, it should be good for posting as generic code golf.

Answer (score 2):

### OEIS A125959

https://oeis.org/A125959 is a sequence I submitted. It is the following array, which then repeats:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    
2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9    
3 6 9 3 6 9 3 6 9    
4 8 3 7 2 6 1 5 9    
5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9    
6 3 9 6 3 9 6 3 9    
7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2 9    
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 9    
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

This is a rather useful array for quickly calculating the digital root of the product of any two numbers (i.e the iterative sum of the digits of the product). See the OEIS link if you're interested in the details.

The challenge is to print the array in the shortest number of bytes.

## Input

None

## Output

The above array. It can be output as strings with new lines, or as a nested array, or an array of strings; but not as a single-line sequence (i.e. the 2d-nature of the array must be reflected in your output).

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: So it's the multiplication table mod 9, except 0s are 9's?

Comment: @xnor is it? I hadn't spotted that before. Does that stop it being an interesting challenge?

Comment: I believe it does (because it is "create a 10x10 table of the function `(-~a*-~b-1)%9+1`" now).

Comment: I think it makes it too similar to generic print-a-multiplication table challenges, but others might disagree.

Answer (score 2):

## Times have changed!

(pun intended)

---

### Preface

As mathematics progressed, mathematicians agreed upon the 'order of operations', to prevent mathematical expressions from becoming ambiguous.

Given the expression \$7 \times 6 + 5 \times 3\$ we know to first evalulate multiplication, giving \$ 42 + 15\$, which is equal to \$57\$.

But  what if another group of mathematicians had agreed to evaluate addition before multiplication? This expression would become \$ 7 \times 11 \times 3\ = 231\$: which is different from our answer by an error of \$305\%\$!

---

### The Challenge

Given a mathematical expression containing `+` (addition), `*` (multiplication), and the digits `0123456789`, we can find:

- \$E_1\$ - the 'real' value of the expression, when multiplication takes precendence.
- \$E_2\$ - the 'alternate' value of the expression, when addition takes precedence.

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a string representing an expression, calculates and outputs the percentage error, \$\frac{|E_1 - E_2|}{E_1} \times 100\$.

---

### Rules

- WIP.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131567/operator-precedence-how-wrong-can-i-be)

Comment: @ChasBrown do you think it's similar enough to call this challenge a dupe?

Answer (score 2):

## Bake the cookie

### Quick intro

So i was playing cookie clicker yesterday, and I thought about something. We keep producing cookies, without any loss. What if your cookies failed? This is where I thought about a clicker that would cook a cookie. Don't click too much, or the cookie will be overcooked!

### Task

Your task will be to create a function that will "bake" a cookie :

- Your function will have to randomly select a number between 5 and 10 : it will establish the cooking duration of your cookie (and so, the number of time you'll have to call the function to cook your delicious cookie).
- Each time you call that function, it will iterate the baking process of your cookie.
- Your function should return "Undercooked" if your cookie is not fully cooked, "Overcooked" if you ... overcooked it, and "Cooked" when the cookie is baked just right.

### Example

Since I'm bad at explaining things, an example will show you more clearly what needs to be done.
Let's call my function bake() :

```
bake()    // The random number generated is 6, so i need to call my function 6 times
Undercooked

bake()
Undercooked

bake()
Undercooked

bake()
Undercooked

bake()
Undercooked

bake()    // We hit the 6th function call, the cookie is baked.
Cooked

bake()    // The 7th call overcooked the cookie. Congratulation, you ruined it.
Overcooked
```

### Rules

- The random number of iterations has to be set the first time you call the function. It has to be between 5 and 10 (inclusive).
- A cookie has to be undercooked before being cooked, and has to be cooked before being overcooked. The 3 steps have to be reachable. A cookie can't uncook itself, therefore you can't go from cooked to undercooked, or from overcooked to cooked (it's too late, you ruined the cookie anyway).
- The function can have as many parameters as you please.
- Classic rules apply, no standard loopholes
- This is codegolf, so the shortest code wins.

---

### Meta

- Is the challenge clear enough ?
- Should I go with this method to iterate the "baking" process ?
- Are there some rules I could add to make it more exciting ?
- Does this challenge exist already ?
- Should we bake pies instead ?

Comment: I'm assuming bake() will take no parameters and will have to store the count somehow, which means you might want to include some rules about file and global variable I/O. I also did a small editing pass.

Comment: @Veskah I never thout about restricting bake()'s parameters, gonna edit the rules to include this particulatiry. Also, thanks for the edits.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you refer to the submission always as a function? Could it not be a program? Similarly, your edit to allow arbitrarily many parameters conflicts with the general tone that seems to imply that we should be storing state between calls. I think you will want to try explaining the task simply, perhaps even to the level of a non-programmer.

Answer (score 2):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/make-a-lost-compass)

Comment: I don't think this is possible? Surely you can't tell what direction is involved with the mirrors, e.g. `/1`, can you tell if the pointer started on `1` going east vs `/` going north?

Comment: @JoKing Hm yeah I think your right.  I will try a little more but you are right that mirrors can't be used.

Comment: @JoKing I actually do think this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Title: When is Hannukah?

## Input

The input will be a year between 1583 and 2250.

## Output

The Gregorian date of the first **evening** of Hannukah that year. That is the day before the first full day of Hannukah.  Your code should output the month and day of the month in any easy to understand human readable form of your choice.

## Examples

```
2013    November 27 
2014    December 16
2015    December 6  
2016    December 24 
2017    December 12 
2018    December 2  
2019    December 22
2020    December 10 
2021    November 28 
2022    December 18
2023    December 7  
2024    December 25 
2025    December 14 
2026    December 4  
2027    December 24
2028    December 12 
2029    December 1  
2030    December 20 
2031    December 9  
2032    November 27 
2033    December 16
```

## How do you do this?

It could hardly be simpler. We start with a couple of definitions:

We define a new inline notation for the division remainder of \$x\$ when divided by \$y\$: $$(x|y)=x \bmod y$$

For any year Gregorian year \$y\$, the *Golden Number*,
$$G(y) = (y|19) + 1$$
For example, \$G(1996)=2\$ because \$(1996|19)=1\$.

To find \$H(y)\$, the first evening of Hannukah in the year \$y\$, we need to find \$R(y)\$ and \$R(y+1)\$, the day of September where *Rosh Hashanah* falls in \$y\$ and in \$y+1\$. Note that September \$n\$ where \$n≥31\$ is actually October \$n-30\$.

$$R(y)=⌊N(y)⌋ + P(y)$$ where \$⌊x⌋\$ denotes \$x-(x|1)\$, the integer part of \$x\$, and

$$N(y)= \Bigl \lfloor \frac{y}{100} \Bigr \rfloor - \Bigl \lfloor \frac{y}{400} \Bigr \rfloor - 2 + \frac{765433}{492480}\big(12G(y)|19\big) + \frac{(y|4)}4 - \frac{313y+89081}{98496}$$

We define \$D_y(n)\$ as the day of the week (with Sunday being \$0\$) that September \$n\$ falls on in the year \$y\$. Further, Rosh Hashanah has to be postponed by a number of days which is

$$P(y)=\begin{cases}
1,  &  \text{if } D_y\big(\lfloor N(y)\rfloor \big)\in\{0,3,5\}  &  (1)\\
1,  &  \text{if } D_y\big(\lfloor N(y)\rfloor\big)=1
 \text{ and } (N(y)|1)≥\frac{23269}{25920}
 \text{ and } \big(12G(y)|19\big)>11  &  (2)\\
2,  &  \text{if } D_y\big(\lfloor N(y)\rfloor \big)=2 \text{ and } (N(y)|1)≥\frac{1367}{2160} \text{ and } (12G(y)|19)>6  &  (3)\\
0,  &  \text{otherwise}  &  (4)
\end{cases}$$

For example, in \$y=1996\$, \$G(y)=2\$, so the \$N(y)\approx13.5239\$. However, since September 13 in 1996 was a Friday, by Rule \$(1)\$, we must postpone by \$P(y)=1\$ day, so Rosh Hashanah falls on Saturday, September 14.

Let \$L(y)\$ be the number of days between September \$R(y)\$ in the year \$y\$ and September \$R(y+1)\$ in year \$y+1\$.

The first evening of Hannukah is:

$$
H(y)=\begin{cases}
83\text{ days after }R(y) & \text{if } L(y)\in\{355,385\}\\
82\text{ days after }R(y) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

## Notes and thanks

Thank you to @Adám for pointing me to the rules. To keep things simple, this challenge assumes the location to be Jerusalem.

Comment: Please type out the rules on that image into actual text. Challenges are supposed to be self-contained, while that image will be subject to link rot. Also, it's lacking an explanation how the Golden Number G is calculated.

Comment: What if the given year has no Hannukah? Or there are two "first day of Hannukah"s in the given year?

Comment: @Adam. Now you have confused me! For which years between 1900 and 2100 were there 0 or 2 Hannukahs?

Comment: @Anush Ah, I didn't notice the range. 3031 will have 0 and 3032 will have 2.

Comment: Hold on, the first **evening**? That'd be the day before *before* the "first **day** of Hannukah". You should be very clear about this.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that there's a risk of people actually not implementing the algorithms, but instead relying on a built-in calendar conversion. Though you don't state it, the answer is always the 24th day of the month Kislev in the Hebrew year CivilYear+3761.

Comment: Also, you may want to extend the valid input range. Otherwise it will often be shortest to hard-code the dates, e.g. in base 30.

Comment: @Adam Could you please double check the formula in the question actually matches the example dates I have given.  If so, I will post the question.

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: OK, I've tried it now and it works. It actually works. However, don't go ahead and post yet; There are a few issues to address.

Comment: The first day of Hannukah day 84 if Rosh Hashanah is day 1, so you need to add 83 to get the first day of Hannukah, but 82 to get the evening before.

Comment: The last three paragraphs are superfluous as your range is bigger. However, I also suggest adjusting the range somewhat. If you go above 2239 then .NET won't help (which may be good or bad depending on whether you want to push people to implement the actual algorithm instead of just converting the Hebrew date using the built-in. In any case, the Hebrew calendar isn't really defined beyond 2250.

Comment: You can however pull back the earliest year to 1583, but not earlier, as that's the first year of the civil calendar.

Comment: The mathematical formulas are really awkwardly written. Maybe MathJax those? I can do it if you want.

Comment: The linked page isn't really "the definitive reference".

Comment: Actually, I suggest rewriting all the quoted text. Things like "Doomsday" being a synonym of "Rosh Hashanah" requires inside information.

Comment: You need test cases that are more spread out, as otherwise they appear cyclic with a 19-year cycle.

Comment: I would adjust the output requirements to read "The Gregorian date of the first evening of Hannukah." to pre-empt people just submitting `print("24 Kislev")`.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem A very good point! :)

Comment: @Adam I would be very grateful if you could mathjax the math.

Comment: @Anush Have a look now.

Comment: @Adam Thank you so much! I made one tiny edit (\bmod instead of \mod).

Answer (score 2):

### Decode the password

Given a *printable ASCII* string separated with spaces, output the specified index of every word. E.g.

```
"are turbas unsafe ?!", 1
```

will yield `run!`

- When the index is out of bounds, this index should yield the null string (which can be joined with other strings).

### More test cases

```
"Is Pascal truly unloyal to users?",3 -> "sure"
"I'd pass kittens to anyone stopping by!!",4 -> "stop!"
```

Comment: The definitive answer here is yes.

Comment: I assume this was just meant to be laying out the idea not to forget about it. But just in case I figured I should say that you definitely need to specify what happens when the index is too large for one of the substrings, and that the rest of the string will be printable ascii / whatever you choose.

Comment: The first test case in the more test cases section seem wrong should it not yield "sule" and not "sure"?

Comment: And the last test case only works for 1-indexing, while all others are 0-indexed.

Comment: What happened to this user?

Answer (score 2):

## Is this entire list likewise-modulus-aligned?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

A pair of numbers are *aligned* in a modulus when they all share the same remainder when they can be put under the modulus function against an integer greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to the absolute value of both.

```
For example,

13 and 22 are aligned numbers under 3 because
13%3 = 1
22%3 = 1

3<=13, 3<=22, and 3>=2

All our requirements are met.
```

A list is likewise-modulus-aligned when all the elements are aligned under the same modulus base.

### Challenge

Take in a list (not necessarily non-empty) of non-zero integers (not necessarily positive nor unique), and check if all the elements are likewise-modulus-aligned. Output is a truthy or falsy value.

Note; This is a "true-until-proven-otherwise" problem, meaning a single value in the list or an empty list will return TRUE.

### Example I/O

```
      In      | Out | Why
--------------|-----|---------
         [5 7]|TRUE |1 mod 2
     [7 12 18]|FALSE|(7,18) are not mod-aligned
     [7 11 19]|TRUE |1 mod 2
  [5 13 28 44]|FALSE|(5,28) are not mod-aligned
[10 13 37 108]|FALSE|(37,108) aren't aligned in any base below 10
            []|TRUE |No disproven pairs
          [42]|TRUE |No disproven pairs
    [-5 13 16]|TRUE |1 mod 3
      [1 9 18]|FALSE|Arrays of size 2 or greater with 1 or -1 will always be false
    [14 17 19]|FALSE|Every pair is modulus-aligned, but not under the same base
[17,22,32,107]|TRUE |2 mod 5
      [4,8,12]|TRUE |0 mod 2
        [-1,1]|FALSE|No mod 1 allowed
           [1]|TRUE |No disproven pairs
       [7,7,7]|TRUE |Numbers >=2 are always mod-aligned with themselves
     [2,2,8,8]|TRUE |0 mod 2
   [3 9 22 22]|FALSE|Pairs don't suddenly make (9,22) mod-aligned.
```

### Sandbox Questions

I'm gauging the interest to this question and seeing if this is an acceptable and unique challenge, just want to make sure I haven't missed another post doing a similar thing.

I changed the rules to be a lot more lenient on the comparisons, might do the pairwise comparison as a bonus or follow-up challenge later. But this is a compromise I can live with.

### Extra Hints/Tips

For all non-1 derivations, a number will be aligned with its negative self.
1 is never aligned with any other number, nor will -1.
A number that is a multiple of another will be aligned with that number in all its factors.
Numbers that share factors will always align, but numbers that *don't* share factors also may.
All odd numbers are aligned with each other, as are all even numbers.

Comment: I'm not clear on why this challenge asks to compare all pairs of a list, rather than just a single pair. The condition covers pairs of numbers, so it would be more natural to just receive a pair of numbers as input.

Comment: Because it's a combination of that function and a list-pair function with interesting shortcuts that can overlap. Asking for a pair could take X bits, and pushing all pairs to a function could take Y, but the combination of the two isn't necessarily X+Y. In my going at it, I saved like 8 bytes in the mix by being clever. This way, there are several ways to solve while still being a challenge.

Comment: Some test cases that are not `1 mod x` would be good

Comment: Good suggestion, Jo. I just added one, and I'll add a few more in a bit - I hadn't even caught that!

Comment: While what you observed can be true, in my experience it is not usually a source of interest in golfing to combine tasks unnecessarily. Similarly, does including negative numbers make this task more interesting? In most languages this will not make a difference, but it will make answering in some languages (consider Retina) substantially more difficult - to the point where people probably won't answer. I always try to recommend making a challenge as simple as possible - just like writing a proof.

Comment: I made negative numbers allowed because negative modulus is still a valid application of modulus - but that argument of "combining two things" is applicable to like literally every other code golf question. The string-wise calculus question could have just been "print out which of two characters is the largest", but then there was added difficulty to comparing pairs and assigning those values to distinct characters. This isn't just an arbitrary expansion, it's a setwise comparison of several elements applied over a function; You see these "expansions" all the time, so why is this one an issue?

Comment: I agree that the part of the challenge where you check every pair seems unnecessary, and was going to comment on this independently. I think just having two numbers as inputs would make a better challenge overall. Or, have all numbers in the list need to be aligned by the same modulus, which seems like a more natural extension.

Comment: Okay, what about a fairer follow-up instead - instead of checking if all pairs are modulus-aligned, a list is modulus-aligned if *all* the entries share an identical mod-point. ie: They all have to be n mod m together for the list to be valid. Think that's still a more fair question? I think submitting pairs only is a very low-level simple problem that doesn't have any real puzzle or golfing elements to it, so I'd like it to be slightly more complex somehow.

Comment: What you and xnor propose sounds good to me. I tried to phrase what I said as suggestions and opinions, because that is all they are. There isn't anything wrong with what you have, but I know I'd be more likely to answer if you changed some things about it. The same is true for many challenges on this site (including my own). Over time, I've come to see that including requirements that are technically valid but aren't necessary rarely adds interest to a challenge.

Comment: Doesn't `[10 13 37 109]` satisfy `1 mod 3` (and therefore it *is* modulus-aligned)?

Comment: You're correct fixed!

Comment: I agree with @JoKing's first answer, some test cases which are truthy but not \$1\pmod x\$ would be nice (i.e. `[17,22,32,107]`, where \$x=5\$).

Comment: Another suggested test case (unless you're changing the specs to only allow positive integers in the input instead of non-zero): `[-1,1] → FALSE`. EDIT: Hmm, `[1]` would result in truthy due to the same reason as `[42]` I guess? In that case you may want to add that one as well, since my prepared solution was correct for all test cases, but returns falsey for `[1]`..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen But that's fine. If I have a list [7, 14], they are aligned under Base 7.

Comment: @Mathgeek Ah, you're correct! We're talking about the base they're aligned to, not the result after that modulo. My bad. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Good suggestions for the example cases! I added a few more in.

Comment: I also just read the "_(not necessarily positive **nor unique**)_" part of your challenge, so you might want to add a few test cases containing multiple of the same number in that case.

Comment: Nice challenge btw. And good choice on explicitly mentioning "_Note; This is a "true-until-proven-otherwise" problem, meaning a single value in the list or an empty list will return TRUE._", since those `[1]`/`[-1]` test cases are really annoying in my approach. ;) I had a prepared solution which worked for all initial test cases in 10 bytes, but now it's 50% larger to 15 bytes just to fix those two test cases, haha. Looking forward to when it goes live. I would leave it in the sandbox for a little while longer for others to give feedback though, just in case. Oh, and welcome to CGCC!

Comment: Is it a worthwhile complication that the modulus must have smaller or equal absolute value than each of input numbers? I think the challenge would be cleaner without it, for instance with [1,3] being modulus aligned, and match how I'd naturally interpret the term.

Comment: @xnor yes, the question then dissolves to finding whether the gcd of the differences of consecutive elements is >1.

Comment: @DonThousand Oh, good point. But then with the condition now, can't you still just take the gcd of the differences of consecutive elements, and check that it's greater than 1 but no more than the smallest absolute value of the inputs?

Comment: @xnor yes, that should work.

Comment: It's exactly this type of reason why I wanted the pairwise list, because you *couldn't* just sort, find the differences, then GCD. Oh well. When you can say "well, can't you just X" then I think it stops being an interesting code golf question.

Comment: I think in many languages the GCD approach will not be shorter. It is true that "just" isn't a great word but `1 < gcd diff sorted x <= min abs x` doesn't seem terribly more simple than `any ( allSame x%m | m = 2 .. min abs x)` (please forgive the bad pseudocode). I think having multiple possible approaches is actually a boon for code golf challenges.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Why does it need to be sorted, by the way? why not gcd diff x? Most languages support gcd on integers, not just naturals.

Comment: @DonThousand I didn't do any analysis myself, I just tried to follow what had been said. Even without sorting I think the point still holds. (Separately, I don't think I ever assumed that gcd would be restricted in that way?)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah, I see. I assumed you thought so because I didn't see the need of sorting elsewise.

Comment: @xnor Are you sure that works for all test cases, though. Take the `[2,2,8,8]` or `[7,7,7]` for example. The differences are `[0,6,0]` and `[0,0]`, for which the GCD is `6` and `0` respectively. But since the first fails the `<= min([2,2,8,8])` check and the second the `> 1` check, they result in falsey instead of truthy. I think that approach only works if all values are unique (and you can't just (connected) uniquify the list first, since then test cases like `[1,1,1]` would result in truthy instead of falsey as well).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good point, I was assuming the elements are unique.

Comment: @xnor I can understand. Before those test cases weren't present yet (although the "_(not necessarily positive nor unique)_" was mentioned from the start. Which is also why I asked for some additional test cases [in an earlier comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18570?noredirect=1#comment66962_18570) to cover that rule.

Answer (score 2):

### [Square-Cube Digit Usage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200215/31625)

Comment: In response to the first sentence: nice.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your title relates to the challenge. Obviously "Square-Cube Digit Usage" won't exactly roll off the tongue, but what you have now seems misleading.

Comment: Nice challenge. I prepared a solution for when it goes live. I would add a few more test cases first, though. One suggestion: `1333 (or 3133/3313/3331) -> 111` (first positive integer as input that has a 3-digit number as output). [Here the results for the first 10,000 inputs.](https://pastebin.com/6f7PGC2W)

Answer (score 2):

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

## Draw an American flag for any amount of states

The flag of the United States of America goes by many names. **The Stars and Stripes**. **Old Glory**. **The Last Known Non-Erotic Usage Of The Verb 'To Spangle'**.

It is also one of the few flags semi-regularly updated. The red and white stripes represent the 13 original states, but one more star has been added to the blue canton for every state that joined the union later. This last happened in 1960, when Hawaii got in. Flag designs with 51 stars are already waiting for when Puerto Rico or Washington D.C. are made states, but this vexillologist is lazy. You are to make a program that can draw the flag with any number of stars desired!

#### Specification

Here's a neat image of the official, government-standardised design for the current U.S. flag:
[image: flag design]

Disregard the contents of the canton for now. Your program must draw a flag that adheres to only the ratios I give here:

- A (the height of the flag) = 1
- B (the width of the flag) = 19/10
- C (the height of the canton) = 7/13
- D (the width of the canton) = 19/25
- L (the height of any stripe) = 1/13

Because raster solutions are not exact and this flag is commonly misdrawn anyway, there's tolerance of 2% for every ratio, taking the flag height as the base.

Furthermore, the correct colours must be used.

- Every odd-numbered stripe must be this shade (hex): #B22234
- The blue canton must be in this shade: #3C3B6E
- Every even-numbered stripe, and every star, must be in this shade: #FFFFFF

Conversions to other colour coordinate systems can be found on [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States#Colors) as well.

#### Stars

Your program must takes as input any integer between 0 and 200, and draw that number of stars within the canton. The following rules apply.

- Each star must have five outer points and be five-fold rotationally symmetrical.
- Each star must be the same size.
- The bounding circles of stars may overlap, but the surface of the stars itself may not overlap.
- The bounding circles of the stars may go outside the canton, but the surface of the stars itself may not go outside the canton.
- I don't want solutions that just place every star on the same line; that would leave a lot of blue canton untouched, which would be a waste. So, as a rule, the combined surface area of the bounding circles of every star in the canton must be at least 20% of the surface area of the canton.

  Since overlapping bounding circles still count, you get a formula for the minimum width *w* of the star, where *a* is the area of the canton and *n* the number of stars: [image: formula]. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%20*%200.2%20%3D%20%28pi%20*%20%28w%2F2%29%5E2%29%20*%20n%3B%20a%20%3E%200%3B%20n%20%3E%200%3B%20w%20%3E%200%20%20solve%20for%20w) for how it's derived.

#### Other specifications

There's no minimum or maximum size for your output image, though I recommend something that will allow 200 stars to fit but still be demonstrably star-shaped. When they are only a few pixels high, it becomes hard to argue that they have the required amount of points. Obviously, for vector solutions any size is permissible.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest program wins!

#### Test cases

Because I gave no specific arrangement of the stars (you may arrange them however you want), there is an infinite number of correct and incorrect solutions for each number of stars. These are just examples of valid and invalid solutions:

Valid:

[image: valid1]

Invalid (stars too small):

[image: invalid1]

Valid:

[image: valid2]

Invalid (stars of unequal size, going out of the canton):

[image: invalid2]

[Invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serapis_flag) (stars have too many points, stripes have wrong colours, colours are the wrong hue, proportions are wrong):

[image: invalid3]

### Sandbox

Do I need more test cases? Any other feedback?

Comment: If you really want to allow 0 as an input, you'll need an exception to the rule that the combined areas of the bounding circle must be at least 20% of the area of the canton.  (If there aren't any stars, there aren't any bounding circles, so the combined areas would be 0.)

Comment: I know it's less thematic, but maybe the task could be just to draw the canton? Arranging and drawing the stars is the interesting part, whereas the stripes aren't changing, so in terms of golfing the stripes seem somewhat extraneous. I guess you could also have the number of stripes be variable.

Answer (score 2):

## Excessively complicated Game of Life [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

In the excessively complicated version of the Game of Life, the world is a \$W \times H\$ square torus with a grid of squares. Each square has a rulestring attached to it - by default, `B/S`.
Each square has a dead or alive cell in it. Each alive cell is controlled by a player. Every turn, if there is not an alive cell in a square, it is born iff the part between `B` and `/` contains the number of alive neighbours. Every turn, if there *is* an alive cell in a square, it survives iff the part after `S` contains the number of alive neighbours. Cells are considered adjacent if they have a common edge or a corner. A cell is not adjacent with itself. Cells controlled by other players also count as alive neighbours.

For example, normal Conway's Game of Life cells have the `B3/S23` rulestring: cells are born if they have exactly 3 alive neighbours, and survive if they have 2 or 3.

Each player starts with a `B/S012345678` cell, placed uniformly randomly.

Each cell knows a 3x3 array of numbers from \$-1\$ to \$1\$, representing adjacent cells (including self). \$1\$ in it means an ally cell, \$0\$ means a dead cell, and \$-1\$ means an enemy cell, and a 3x3 array of rulestrings for adjacent cells.

Every turn, every cell can alter one bit of the rulestring of any adjacent square (including its own) - that is, remove or add a number from it (or, alternatively, it can do nothing).

When cells are born, the player they belong to is chosen semi-randomly: the odds of the cell being assigned to a player are proportional to the number of cells they contributed to the cell's birth.

A player is eliminated when all their cells die.
When \$N\$ turns passed, or when only one player remains, the game ends. A full point is distributed between all remaining players proportionally to the number of cells they control (dead cells don't count).

### Clarifications

- Rulestrings are attached to squares, not to cells. When a cell dies, the rulestring on its square is not changed.
- No cell can be born with zero alive adjacent cells (that is, rulestrings cannot start with `B0`).
- When multiple cells attempt to alter the same bit in a rulestring, it is only affected once.

### Challenge

Define a pure function \$(nearbyStates, nearbyRules)\to(\Delta x, \Delta y, index)\$ to be used as the algorithm for your cells. To do nothing, output an index of 0.

Otherwise, an index of 1 corresponds to toggling `B1`, 2 to `B2` and so on until `B8`, the index 9 is skipped, then an index of 10 corresponds to toggling `S0`, 11 to `S1` and so on until `S8`.

### Winning criterion

\$X\$ games are run, and the leaderboard is formed by sorting participants by the total number of points.

This is [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), so whoever wins wins!

## Sandbox stuff

- Is this a good idea?
- Is the description of the game clear?

I think I decided that the language for submissions will be Javascript. Now I have to write a controller.

Besides the obvious Javascript option, I am considering C++ with a Javascript engine (probably V8). This can multiply the performance by \$\%NUMBER\_OF\_PROCESSORS\% \cdot \frac{cppPerformance}{jsPerformance} \cdot \frac{myC++skill}{myJSskill}\$, which can be quite large. Unfortunately, that might also muptiply the challenge's popularity by \$\frac{webBrowserLoadingSpeed}{programInstallationSpeed}\$, which can be quite small! Would that be a good idea?

Comment: **Disclaimer:** I'm biased in both categories. **Language:** Leaning towards JS, especially since this challenge seems to be of the "hack around and *see* what works" type, and I believe browser-based ones shine here the most. Python seems to be popular as well, but AFAIK it's usually used for challenges that don't need rich visualization. Other languages, like Java, .NET, C++, etc., can also be considered, of course (higher performance)... **Orientation:** Removing orientation does seem to be a good fit. It increases the amount of interactions that can happen between any two entries.

Comment: Regarding C++: You can have your cake and eat it too. Have you heard of [Wasm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly) and [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)? This combination lets you get near-native peformance along with multithreading all in the browser.

Comment: Note that improving controller performance only gets you so far. You're gonna have to go the Formic route and cache entry responses in some smart way to extract all the potential of C++.

Comment: @Alion I include "caching in some smart way" in "improving controller performance". I have also considered using Emscripten (and started using it, starting with the renderer first, because I randomly decided so) but then I got worried because I thought calling JS from WASM and WASM from JS is going to be too slow. After reading the comment, I googled and it turned out Emscripten **has** multithreading. I guess I'll continue now.

Comment: I'd like to see a good C/C++ KoTH. I'm always excluded from them because I don't know any languages that they're in.

Comment: @SSAnne I do not understand your comment. Are you proposing a C/C++ KoTH, or are you stating that they cannot be good because you don't know these languages?

Answer (score 2):

### Symmetrical difference [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Post'd.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203364/symmetrical-difference)

Comment: If a language supports it, can we take output and input as `set`s instead of a `list`s?

Answer (score 2):

[Posted on the main site.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204061)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. Post it.

Answer (score 2):

## Help, I've mixed my week up!

My dog ate my calendar, and now my days are all mixed up. I tried putting it back together, but I keep mixing up the days of the week! I need some help putting my calendar back together, with the days in the correct order.

And since I need my calendar put together as fast as possible, don't waste my time by sending me superfluous bytes. The fewer bytes I have to read, the better!

### Input

The days of the week, in any order. Input can be taken as a list of strings, or a space separated string, or any reasonable way of representing 7 strings (one for each day of the week).

The strings themselves are all capitalized, as weekdays should be, so the exact strings are:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

### Output

The days of the week, in sorted order (Monday - Sunday). Output can be as a list of strings, or printed with some delimiter.

### Disclaimer

Note that this is a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge, with the added benefit of being able to use the input to shorten your code. You are not required to use the input if you don't want to.

### Examples

To see example input and output, you can consult [this python script](https://tio.run/##dYxLCsMgFEXnrkIyUgiZdCZkAR11CeG1T4lUn@IHdPVpoMmgpZ3ec86NvayBLttmfQyp8Ac4TQiJmdmBvyPwpvIONIo2PnU/V1TO5iJOfULoC4HXcrKEugmU8rxMQBg8y2s1xmlcdjXzmf/p2VufDl18ZJLFZKmI4UqxFjWM/De@1XJw83Ugtxc).

### For the sandbox

If there are any issues with the input/output specification, or if anything is unclear, please leave a comment.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)

Comment: You cannot use 6 tags, and this still needs [code-golf]. Otherwise this seems to be a nice challenge. (I can see a 4-6 Jelly solution by sort-nth permutation though)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I forgot about the [tag:code-golf] tag, but of course it should be there. I have my own solution in MathGolf (not quite 4 bytes), but I'm interested in different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

## Fold my ACGT proteins [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [biology](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) [chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

Quoting Wikipedia, *"Protein folding is the physical process by which a protein chain acquires its native 3-dimensional structure, a conformation that is usually biologically functional, in an expeditious and reproducible manner."*. I don't know what that means *but* by means of a game called [Foldit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldit) it seems we can use protein folding in some way to help and fight diseases.

Please bear in mind that the task described was inspired by the isolated meaning of the words in *"protein folding"* and doesn't necessarily translate into how protein folding really works! i.e. the title is just a pun.

## Task

Your task is to take a string matching the regex `/^[ACGT]+$/` and return the number of times the string can be "folded". A string can be folded if and only if:

- It's length is even;
- The first half of the string is the reverse of the second half of the string.

## Input

Acceptable input formats include but are not limited to:

- strings
- character lists
- codepoint lists

## Output

The output is an integer; I don't think there's much room to wiggle here, but let me know if you really wanted to return something else.

## Test cases:

[Python reference implementation](https://tio.run/##fVJRb4IwEH7nV1xYFmGKDp2bMXOJ4cE/wJsxBqRoF2hJKQ@L8be7O0AsZtlLe9/1@67fXVv86JMUs@s1VTIHFYkEN54XUukWWVbCUkhlluxz5hRKasaFu7QAeAoZE13qeUpJAMV0pQS8ImBZyZrkKcpSWEHL3S5N4WQy3dUkLFjzhvW2XS49fwerTtVU6i7wkXezRXy3Pr5faTjpWnDiqGQj6PwLqUH0bBPBag6b/h0XPuF1PO@xulpDWhqnWNbz3V7Xj@yGOGxNENvSrNT7AyZKHM92Z1lPIJMERJXHTLGEJnzUp9JKpQIOXJCrI3P8EXyMYFr3cS8xjoqCicSx1/YLd6nWd1VqiKDMoyyDnJdFFh1YzoRGHdnAS4m8eKy/@K8yDt4ObVoROQuPYyfUitzHFc8SagTFyA02oU0uRyac9eFbC8N1EBhkUxiuCc1vOozf2zgw4o0Rh0bcEwcbE6xNP2jAQHjWYXwVGk@Mb0YTuvX594Sax6Y/5l5JRYxa1TFJVygutJPagzPlLwPwvuB8@82Uci@2e/0F)

```
'A' -> 0
'AAA' -> 0
'AAAAA' -> 0
'TAAAAAAA' -> 0
'ATAAAAAA' -> 0
'AATAAAAA' -> 0
'AAATAAAA' -> 0
'AAAATAAA' -> 0
'AAAAATAA' -> 0
'AAAAAATA' -> 0
'AAAAAAAT' -> 0
'TGCAACGTTGCAACGT' -> 2
'ACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCA' -> 3
'TGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGTTGCAACGT' -> 4
'TACCCCATTACCCCAT' -> 2
'TTTT' -> 2
'TATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTATTAT' -> 5
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' -> 6
'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC' -> 6
'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG' -> 6
'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT' -> 6
'TAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAAT' -> 5
'GCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCGGCCG' -> 5
'CATTACCATTACCATTACCATTAC' -> 3
'CATTACCATTACCATTACCATTAC' -> 3
'CATACCATACCATACCATACCATACCATACCATACCATAC' -> 3
```

Comment: Where did you get the "The first half of the string is the reverse of the second half of the string." requirement from?

Comment: @Lyxal I do not understand the question

Comment: Protein folding is usually related to amino acids, which are based on groups of 3 nucleic bases. And usually, it doesn't really matter what order they are in. I say this because the `ATCG`s you have aren't amino acids. They are nucleic bases which, when converted into RNA (which uses `U` instead of `T`) become amino acids.

Comment: @Lyxal ah I understand what you mean. I have added this sentence: Please bear in mind that the task described was inspired by the isolated meaning of the words in "protein folding" and doesn't necessarily translate into how protein folding really works. This addresses your issue, right? Also, this probably means the tag you added doesn't really make sense here, no? What do you think? (On the other hand if you know how PF works I'm glad to talk with you to forge a more closely related challenge)

Comment: it's been a while since I last studied PF, but if it's an isolated meaning/simplified approach, then that seems fine to me.

Comment: I think it's just a pun isn't it? Not literally "folding" proteins in the usual complicated 3 dimensional fashion, but just folding them a string supposedly representing a protein in half.

Comment: @SteveBennet dang it! I missed the joke.

Answer (score 2):

### Integers in cosine

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204610/integers-in-cosine)

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but doesn't \$\sin(x) = -\cos(x+\frac{\pi}2)\$?

Comment: You are right, it's either `-cos` or `-k`

Comment: I think the question would be clearer if you stated that \$\sin(a) = -\cos[a+(4m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}]\$ for integer \$m\$. Also, the sentence 'Instead of `pi/2` we could use integers that are near the actual value of `sin(a)`' is not correct: \$|\sin(a)|\le1\$. I guess you mean values of \$k\$ that are close to \$(4m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\$ for some \$m\$. But in that case, \$k=14\$ is better than \$k=11\$ for 2 digits. (I haven't checked all 2-digit values.)

Comment: I based my challenge on this blog post: https://www.iquilezles.org/blog/?p=4760
It's for reducing coding in shader live coding session mostly. I calculated myself the closest values and |cos(33)| is much bigger than |cos(11)| so I changed that and the 5 digit one, but the other values are minimal.

Comment: You seem to be seeking integer values of \$k\$ for which \$|\cos(k)|\$ is minimal. That's a very different question from finding values of \$k\$ such that \$\sin(a)\approx-\cos(a+k)\$, which is the question you've actually posted here and what the blog post describes (with missing minus signs).

Comment: yeah sorry, I got confused how those values got calculated, let me rephrase the challenge then

Comment: Thanks for the edits. This looks better now, though I'd suggest using MathJax (\\\$ delimiters) for the maths. What is the scoring/winning criterion for this challenge? (Is it [tag:code-golf]? [tag:fastest-code]?)

Comment: Almost there... but you have \$\pi\$ in the wrong place. It should be in the numerator: \$\frac{(4m+1)\pi}{2}\$.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first challenge and I haven't used latex in a while so every help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

## Produce a range

Your task is to take a list of integers and find inputs to a Python `range` call to produce that list. That is, output three values `(start, stop, step)` so that `range(start, stop, step)` equals the given list.

You can assume that this is possible, which means that consecutive numbers in the list all have the same nonzero difference. Be careful that your code works for negative step sizes, as well as for empty or singleton inputs.

**How `range` works**

Python's built-in [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range) produces a list* of equally-spaced numbers. Called as `range(start, stop, step)`, it counts from the `start` value in increments of `step` like

```python
[start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]
```

This list continues as long as the value is below `stop` given positive `step`, or above `stop` given negative `step`. If the `start` value already fails this test, an empty list is produced. Note that the `stop` value itself is never included in the list, giving a half-open interval.

```python
range(0, 5, 1)   = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
range(0, -5, -1) = [0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
range(0, 2, -1)  = []
range(0, -2, 1)  = []
range(3, 4, 10)  = [3, 7]
range(3, 4, 11)  = [3, 7]
range(3, 4, 12)  = [3, 7, 11]
range(1, -2, 0)  = [1]
```

*In Python 3, it actually makes a `range` object, but we'll ignore that distinction.

**Test cases**

Note that there can be multiple valid inputs. Different `stop` values can cut off the result at the same point when the step is not `±1`. A singleton or empty list can be produced in many ways.

TODO

Comment: Is this `return {a[0], a[-1]+sign(a[1]-a[0]), a[1]-a[0]}`?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I think that works for inputs with 2+ elements, though the empty list and singleton list also need to be handled. Is this too simple for a challenge?

Comment: (I just noticed this might work in languages with modular indexing) This is probably not too simple, and I like the idea, but it seems like most of the complexity here comes from these special cases.

Comment: Both Python 2 and Python 3 disagree with step=0 in range. `range(1, -2, 0)` would raise `ValueError` instead. Is this intend behavior in this challenge? Also, some languages (Matlab) would support range with floating point values, which some floating point errors may introduced. If you are not aiming to work on floating point errors, maybe add a [tag:integer] tag.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bilibili AV/BV Code Conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204912/bilibili-av-bv-code-conversion)

Comment: Can I share part of the two functions? (though it likely make them search)

Comment: I would say no, because the two functions should be independent. I will clarify this in the requirements. You may have identical parts in both function, but they will be double-counted.

Comment: Oh I meant each code should work even without the code from the other. Hope this will be clear enough for the requirement

Comment: Consider deleting this post, as the challenge is already on main

Answer (score 2):

## Minimise my List of Error Codes

### SANDBOX - One Option for a Challenge

Given a set of error codes, formed of letters (A-Z) and numbers (0-9), output a string that represents the set of error codes in a concise format, as follows:

- Where two or more error codes share some first characters, there is no need to repeat those characters in the output
- Individual errors in the output are comma-separated (or in separate array indices, if preferred)

e.g:

- `E1`,`E2` -> `E1,2`
- `E1`,`W1` -> `E1,W1`
- `ERR001`, `ERR002`, `ERR101`, `WAR001` -> `ERR001,2,101,WAR001` or `WAR001,ERR001,2,101`
- `WARN001`, `ERR001` -> `WARN001,ERR001`
- `EAR001`, `ERR001` -> `EAR001,RR001`
- `E001`, `E001` -> `E001,`
- `A`, `B`, `C01`, `D002` -> `A,B,C01,D002`
- `D002`, `DC01`, `DC0A`, `DC0B` -> `D002,C01,A,B` or `DC01,A,B,002` or `DC0A,B,1,002`etc.

Basically, when decoding, each character after the comma replaces the characters at the end of the previous error code.

### SANDBOX - Alternative Challenge?

Decode a string of error codes, as per the above format, to extract the individual list of error codes again

## SANDBOX - Questions

I know the spec is incomplete above - this is a placeholder for when I have time to write a better spec.

Is this an interesting [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge? Which of the two options would work best? Or could it be the sum of the two (encoder and decoder)?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Draw this planar graph](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98436/draw-this-planar-graph).

Your input represents an ascending sequence, e.g. `1 2 3 4`. You can require the sequence as input, or you can just input the length. The explanation assumes 1-indexing but you can use 0-indexed or even `a`-indexed input if you adjust the algorithm appropriately.

At each step, you can exchange any digit of value `n` with the digit `n` places to its right. So the valid second steps are `2 1 3 4` and `1 4 3 2`. Eventually you want to end up at the reverse sequence `4 3 2 1`, which is the only permutation that has no legal steps.

Please output all possible sequences of steps from the input sequence to its reverse.

You should support sequences of up to at least 10 elements.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I really like this graph's symmetries, so +1! "All such sequences"? For n=1,2,3,4 there are 0,1,2,82 such paths through the graph; I don't think enumerating all of them will be practical even for n=6.

Comment: There might be some questions that can be answered for this special graph more efficient (in terms of code-size) than general graph-searching algorithms: Shortest path, longest path? - I assume there is be a function f on the graph such that f(v)<f(w) iff there's a path from v to w (but right now I don't know) - if that's interesting enough, implement that?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Wizard creating a jewelry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98424/wizard-creating-a-jewelry).

Given an input list of positive integers, calculate the minimum cost of creating the list from the following operations:

1. Appending a positive integer costs the value of the integer.
2. Incrementing the entire list costs 2.
3. Exchanging two consecutive elements of the list costs 1.

Example: The list `1 4 9 16 25` could be constructed as follows:

- Append 1
- Append 8
- Append 17
- Increment
- Increment
- Increment
- Increment
- Increment
- Append 1
- Swap 22 with 1
- Swap 13 with 1
- Swap 6 with 1
- Increment
- Increment
- Increment
- Append 1
- Swap 25 with 1
- Swap 16 with 1
- Swap 9 with 1
- Swap 4 with 1

This costs 51, which is an improvement over simply appending the integers, as that is a cost of 54.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: Seems clear, but another test case or two might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Reduce the entropy of the input...

### Spec

Given two arguments:

- A list containing 2 or more positive integers (from 0 to artificial limit of 2^32)
- A positive number defining the 'entropy allowance'

Return a sublist containing elements up until the entropy allowance is used up.

For this challenge, we define 'entropy' as the difference in bits between numbers in the list; also known as the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Note that no 'entropy' is used up when flipping the bits in the first number, only used when flipping subsequent bits.

### Examples

Worked example (MSB...LSB), keeping the numbers low to keep things simple:

**Example 1:**

List: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
Allowance: `4`

```
1 => 0000 0001 - ignore implicit change from 0, total used = 0
2 => 0000 0010 - change of 2 bits, total used = 2
3 => 0000 0011 - change of 1 bit, total used = 3 
4 => 0000 0100 - change of 3 bits, total used = 6 (would exceed allowance)
5 => 0000 0101 - change of 1 bit, total used = 7
6 => 0000 0110 - change of 2 bits, total used = 9
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3]`

**Example 2:**

List: `[255, 0, 127, 64, 32, 100]`
Allowance: `23`

```
255 => 1111 1111 - ignore implicit change from 0, total used = 0
0   => 0000 0000 - change of 8 bits, total used = 8
127 => 0111 1111 - change of 7 bit, total used = 15
64  => 0100 0100 - change of 6 bits, total used = 21
32  => 0010 0000 - change of 2 bit, total used = 23
100 => 0110 0100 - change of 2 bits, total used = 25
```

Output: `[255, 0, 127, 64, 32]`

### Meta

Is this interesting enough a challenge? Is it just a chameleon (is it just the hamming distance with extra steps)? Thoughts?

If it's not shot down for being a plain, any ideas for a better title?

Comment: Guess allowing removing arbitary least item is more interesting

Comment: What about a slight pivot - given a list and an allowance, return the list that maximise length of the list?

Answer (score 2):

## The smallest positive integer that cannot be printed in fewer than %NUMBER% bytes of %LANGUAGE% [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

All numbers mentioned below are positive integers. All programs mentioned below output exactly 1 number (including functions that return it).

For every number, there must be at least one program in your language that outputs it. Besides, the problem of determining what number the program outputs must be undecidable without making the assumption that the program halts.

The challenge itself is to choose a number \$N\$ and find the smallest number \$M\$ that cannot be output by a program shorter than \$N\$ ordinary units of measurement used for your language (usually bytes). You have to prove your solution correct. A strong mathematical proof is not necessary, but it should be reasonably convincing for somebody knowledgeable in your programming language.

The answer with the largest \$M\$ wins.

## Sandbox stuff

- In this challenge, non-golfing languages seem to have a serious advantage. I think scoring by \$M\$ instead of \$N\$ is better at reducing the advantage of Lenguage-like languages to manageable levels and preventing ties; is that correct?
- Is the [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) tag appropriate?
- Title suggestions?

Comment: I feel like I misunderstand. Let's say `print M` (where `M` is a normal base 10 integer) is the only valid way to output integers in my language. I take \$N=7\$, then \$M=1\$. What's to stop me repeatedly increasing \$N\$ by 1 and adding a zero on to \$M\$ each time?

Comment: @Dingus I used to have a complicated rule to prevent exactly this; I'll try to think of a simpler one.

Comment: I'm worried that the proof will just be an exhaustive search for most language, as \$M\$ has to be the *smallest* number. Alternatively, we could make \$M\$ a lower bound of the smallest value, and score a solution based on both \$M\$ and \$N\$. Another way is to flip this challenge to find the largest printable number in \$N\$ bytes, but that has already been done [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-bytes-of-code/31703).

Comment: @Dingus I think you will have to stop when you can't prove whether whatever precedes `print M` halts or doesn't halt. I still think this is too cheap a way to get a high-scoring answer, but I am not sure how to formalize things better.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I think my question is probably not relevant. I overlooked a critical condition - 'the problem of determining what number the program outputs must be undecidable without making the assumption that the program halts'.

Comment: I'm worried that some ridiculously large numbers will show up here. Also, as \$N\$ gets too large, maybe we will encounter problems like \$M\$ cannot be calculated assuming axioms of ZFC, what will happen then?

Comment: @Trebor As far as I understand, each program either does output a number within finite time or doesn't output a number within finite time. If the program outputs a number, its result is known, and if it doesn't, the program is not valid because it doesn't output a number in finite time. Can you think of any particular way to obtain a ridiculously large number?

Comment: A simple example is a program that enumerates all the valid proofs in ZFC and outputs the Godel encoding of the first proof it encounters of \$A \wedge \neg A\$. Since ZFC cannot prove its own consistency, it is not decidable in ZFC whether this program terminates. Worse still, if the program do terminate, ZFC cannot compute the return value either, because it is now inconsistent, rendering its deductions unreliable.

Comment: @Trebor Halting and printing a single number is completely binary. Are you sure you are reading the challenge correctly? I'm asking not for the largest number that can be printed, but for the smallest number that can't be printed.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes, that's why I'm "worried" instead of "sure". Also, these problems will not show up if we keep it small...

Answer (score 2):

## Self-distances completion - Minimum k to get them all

*[Related minor code-golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205678/94346)*

Consider \$A = (a_1,\dots,a_k)\ k\ge2 \$ a sequence of positive integers, in which all elements are different.

The *self-distances completion* of a sequence like \$A\$ it's performed recursively as follow:

Starting from \$i=2\$, while \$a_i\in A:\$ <sub>*(loop until the last element)*</sub>

- If \$d=|a_i-a_{i-1}|\$ is not already in \$A\$, append \$d\$ to \$A\$
- Increase \$i\$

The resulting sequence \$A^\circ\$ is presumably longer than \$A\$, nevertheless can't contain more than \$n\$ terms.

## Examples

$$
A = (2,\ 9,\ 13,\ 15) \mapsto A^\circ = (2,\ 9,\ 13,\ 15,\ 7,\ 4,\ 8,\ 3,\ 5)\\
A = (2,\ 9,\ 13) \mapsto A^\circ = (2,\ 9,\ 13,\ 7,\ 4,\ 6,\ 3)\\
A = (2,\ 9) \mapsto A^\circ = (2,\ 9)
$$

## Task

If we pick a number \$n\ge 2\$, we can ask what's the minimum length \$k_n\$ of \$A\$ such that \$A^\circ\$ contains all the numbers up to \$n\$.

*(Note that \$\max A = \max A^\circ\$ so \$n\$ has to be in \$A\$)*

- Generate the sequence of \$k_n\$ starting from \$n=2\$.

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).

I'll run your code on my machine (Windows 10, i7-7500U) **for 30 minutes**.
Obviously longer sequence is better. In case of a tie, who gets to the last term faster wins.
Your submission must not use more than 8GB of memory.
Please include instructions for how to compile/run your code.

## First values and more info

```
 n. k_n - first A* example found (how many A of lenght k_n that satisfy the condition)

 2.  2  - 1 2 (2)
 3.  2  - 1 3 2 (4)
 4.  2  - 4 1 3 2 (2)
 5.  2  - 5 4 1 3 2 (1)
 6.  3  - 1 6 2 5 4 3 (19)
 7.  3  - 3 1 7 2 6 5 4 (10)
 8.  3  - 6 1 8 5 7 3 2 4 (3)
 9.  4  - 6 1 9 2 5 8 7 3 4 (80)
10.  4  - 10 1 8 3 9 7 5 6 2 4 (39)
11.  4  - 6 8 1 11 2 7 10 9 5 3 4 (18)
12.  4  - 8 12 1 10 4 11 9 6 7 2 3 5 (7)
13.  4  - 5 3 12 13 2 9 1 11 7 8 10 4 6 (2)
14.  5  - 6 14 3 1 13 8 11 2 12 5 9 10 7 4 (68)
15.  5  - 9 13 3 1 15 4 10 2 14 11 6 8 12 5 7 (17)
16.  5  - 11 16 2 15 12 5 14 13 3 7 9 1 10 4 8 6 (9)
17.  5  - 14 15 9 13 17 1 6 4 16 5 2 12 11 3 10 8 7 (1)
18.  5  - 15 18 6 16 17 3 12 10 1 14 9 2 13 5 7 11 8 4 (1)
19.  6  - 16 10 18 1 4 19 6 8 17 3 15 13 2 9 14 12 11 7 5 (38)
20.  6  - 14 5 20 17 1 19 9 15 3 16 18 10 6 12 13 2 8 4 11 7 (8)
21.  6  - 12 19 3 21 20 6 7 16 18 1 14 9 2 17 13 5 15 4 8 10 11 (1)
22.  6  - 20 12 19 3 21 22 8 7 16 18 1 14 9 2 17 13 5 15 4 10 11 6 (1)
23.  7  - 22 4 23 14 16 1 21 18 19 9 2 15 20 3 10 7 13 5 17 6 8 12 11 (46)
24.  7  - 15 21 1 23 13 10 24 6 20 22 3 14 18 2 19 11 4 16 17 8 7 12 9 5 (14)
25.  8  - 19 23 2 22 9 1 25 7 4 21 20 13 8 24 18 3 17 5 16 6 15 14 12 11 10 (942)
26.  8  - 18 25 8 2 24 1 21 26 7 17 6 22 23 20 5 19 10 11 16 3 15 14 9 13 12 4 (254)
27.  8  - 27 1 25 20 6 22 18 3 26 24 5 14 16 4 15 23 2 19 9 12 11 8 21 17 10 13 7 (74)
```

*[The veeery elementary program I used.](https://tio.run/##fVTbctowEH2Wv2JDh4wd7A7uY0H0QyjTMbZIFhtBfWnTZvh2uruSjZ3OJDMxkvbs7eyR8uQ5z2@3T2jzqisMrJu2wPPnl00wOapwz2dBZxt8tqYAtC08ZTE85fR/yl7p23T71RRgYyhjIOuPyli9pGVXtXipMMf2j16uguDXGQu41AQOo@AtAPpjR1zJUgyHcDbvYph3kMAslpiRMx/ONYRIcQDXPgktF4sIXKRpCHYm1BZ33v0aqN4azrtoNi0vmpbw3c7o5OorbszPkLOoSbuo0xiOmlpGjKFYBSpQv1@wMiE@6KPgVQEasi0m6W5DPzv45neJ7L7yTtZ0RP4KuT36lTDULK59HIWHkGC407rwJwNYqX1tslKWV8ESKbzjDfkheo9se9zpQnBHhxhiCFTOrtwGe208x865nyoyejLXdCiY68VIUgnzVK3UvHpX1BVM1RjgJFpPs4wCu2oc9M1xU75L1bfFmZb/ZRnGdzH1yc1PZjwdYgytOV3c9ANFGuslVibpIC@l8m2fg0emSfxbaUzoyrcEdubMLa2oQXQjK0dzP9Z16YISAxx36IQrcYLxnBFD8y/9vEUybGUfB1B@Q8euC5bAnbKRz3JwWE7R/OnrdG320rgr4958r5HhZnT7xrQhM9m0Wd3GjlRbmNf@gk/pdkTjgVhgEGgNRJhr0c2pv62jKy@heSY2SeHxEWyCsGFHieGmJPj7QyADYit3i4t0NbZIyYs0doUu0iEntcVVnjK0XjDKisBL@sL9gvuCraPKnXkhP2ivZVV6IjOqgC5oVZ3zkJ5Q@9TgX3M@hGNiIk//CEovbfkBlNKNwPIkfxSZuh7BaRdDyMR/7MJE0Tu@jHol@Lebt6UQI/qvTdvVFkgh19vtHw) There aren't any optimizations, it's just for reference.*

*For the purpose of the challenge you don't have to output examples nor the count. `k_n` is sufficient*

*(It doesn't appear in OEIS).*

## Conjectures

- The sequence of \$k_n\$ is monotonically increasing
- \$k_{n+1}=k_{n}\lor k_{n+1}=k_{n}+1\$

## Sandbox

- It's all clear and does it makes sense?
- Any suggestion for a "lighter" name of the process other than "self-distance completion"?

Comment: The alignment of **Examples** is fine in the main post preview :)

Comment: A *k*-permutation of *n* seems to be a permutation of some *k*-element subset for {1, ..., n}, right?

Comment: @retzler Exactly, equivalently a non-repetitive sequence of integers. And then we consider its max element _n_. I prefer to keep the notation of _k_-permutation of _n_ containing _n_ since doesn't require the notion of max and also it's more linear for what comes next

Comment: If the growth of k_n is unknown, an algorithm's complexity might come in the form f(k_n). **Edit** Ah well, tagged fastest-code. Maybe there's another ambiguity: Maybe still require an example for each n - otherwise what's to prevent `printf("2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7");`

Comment: @retzler I decided to go for fastest-code since looking around fastest-algorithm are not so popular. And as you spotted, the complexity of the algorithm wouldn't be straightforward (and I know almost nothing how it's calculated). About the output I think that to hardcode a sequence it's automatically seen as cheat. [Look](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204149/generate-a065825)

Comment: Some comments: (1) The description is a little difficult to follow, but I think it's because the problem is that hard to define. You can't probably get the description much clearer than it is now. (2) In the "Task" section you ask for the minimum `k` such that its completion contains all numbers up to `n`. However, the math section right afterwards requires, if I'm interpreting it correctly (four quantifiers in a row is a little too much for me), that `k` _and all numbers above it_ satisfy that property. (3) Maybe give a few more details about your computer: RAM, even cache memory

Comment: (4) _Your submission must not use more than 8GB of memory_: isn't that platform-dependent to some extent? (5) Typo: "lenght"

Comment: @LuisMendo (1) The question was very instinctive, but maybe I've convoluted it too much. Playing with the completion I asked myself how can I "generate" all the number up to a certain one. Of course is interesting to find the _minimum requirements_ that is the _minimum (starting) length_. Now one particular thing to notice is that the new terms added are always smaller that the max element in the input string (that's because we are always adding distances). So if I hope to generate all the number up to 20, of course 20 has to be within the input string

Comment: @LuisMendo That's why I define \$\mathcal{A}_{n,k}\$ to be all the sequences of length \$k\$ **having \$n\$ as their max element**. All the completion of all the sequences in one of these sets always keep the same max element \$n\$, (the only thing that can change is the resulting length). It's in these sets that make sense to search if it exists one sequence that maps to the "full" \$n\$-sequence. It's a guideline not a rule (maybe it does more harm than good)

Comment: @LuisMendo (2) Yes, you've interpreted it correctly. It's nothing special, basically when you find the smaller `k` that works, _all the numbers above it_ automatically work as well. Take the working sequence you found of length `k`, you can find a `k+1` sequence if you incorporate the first \$d\$ appended, you can find a `k+2` long sequence incorporating also the second \$d\$ appended in the original one. So, they will all work above a certain threshold. (3-4) I was borrowing [from this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51266/94346)

Comment: @DomenicoModica (2) Ah, maybe clarify that in the text then. On the face of it, they seem different statements

Comment: @LuisMendo I've pared it down substantially. I don't know why I thought all that notation was fundamental ahahaha. Anyway I'll wait sometimes to post it because I want to experiment a bit with it to have a bigger picture and maybe find some useful reductions

Answer (score 2):

### Can this month tell the day-of-the-week? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

June 2020 is a month in which June 1st corresponds to Monday, June 2nd corresponds to Tuesday, ... June 7th corresponds to Sunday. For reference, here's the `cal` of June 2020.

```
      June 2020     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30
```

Given a year and a month in the format `[year, month]`, output two distinct values that tell whether this month can tell the day-of-the week.

### Test cases

````
[2020,6] -> True
[2021,2] -> True
[1929,4] -> True

[1969,1] -> False
[1997,5] -> False
[2060,1] -> False
```
````

Comment: Have you considered "Does this month start on Monday?"

Answer (score 2):

## Print the SARS-Cov-2 (COVID-19) genome [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

### Background

As you probably learned in biology class, DNA and RNA are composed of strands of nucleotides; each nucleotide consists of a chemical called a base together with a sugar and a phosphate group. The information stored in the DNA or RNA is coded as a sequence of bases. DNA uses the bases A, C, G, and T (standing for adenine, cytosine, guanine, and thymine), while RNA uses A, C, G, and U (with uracil replacing thymine).

### Challenge

The genome of SARS-Cov-2, the virus that causes COVID-19, has been fully sequenced. This genome is a sequence of 29,903 bases, each base being one of A, C, G, or U, since it's an RNA virus.

**The challenge is to output that sequence using as few bytes in your program as possible (code golf).** You can write either a full program or a function.

Because the names A, C, G, and U are arbitrary, you can use any 4 characters you want instead:

- You must use exactly 4 characters (they must be pairwise distinct--two or more can't be equal).
- Each one of the 4 characters must be a printable ASCII character in the range from `'!'` to `'~'`, inclusive (ASCII 33 to 126). In particular, this does *not* include the space character or the newline character.
- Each of the 4 characters you use must always represent the same one of A, C, G, and U -- no changing in the middle!

Your output should be the precise text at the following link, with A, C, G, and U replaced by whichever 4 characters you selected, and you may optionally follow the entire sequence with one or more newline characters (but no newlines or other extraneous characters at the beginning or in the middle are allowed):

[Click to see the required output](https://tio.run/##fZ1dki3JbYPXxuADV8AF2E9@9/7D6iI@IM9IEZZGuj23z09VJpMEQZD13//1v//zf3//qd2qmtm/P7e6d7v7@/eq/vvF38/639/ve2r777/798v78e9N379/Lxu95O9H/eLvv/P92X9/3fdj19///l4x34/9/eLvz/m@9C7h@z79eG/7@@ip7zrqe2Hd5Xx/@/ea7wru8/Sx3zvu8r/f9vfN97u@q/3@@b7ue1P9vGruCut7Uelm/17992XzvfG7wb9FWL3@bu572XcldW@/a6nvt9@rvz/3rvX79L8XfxdxF3s/fVeoj25d39T9893GXd53H/e5peu8/fiu5lsmFvJbtu8iblnqrrnve78L0PZ8O/Bd/bdCtwp389/Vf5c1pWv6Xvp98Peu7wa///@uY@6T5276W7HRet8X1d7d3jJ/d/Vd0t4N3ffOLZcX7T5wvsv7TOGzHd9BfxuuVdI/Wvb72Nv/W5e7gr83/H3Od7ffb5vNvJd8X3C28a2JVvt7E8v1vezWdW4NtX/avG/h74pvJ3WTuvjv0r6N0bbu3M93yd@3/33LrUHJlLW83/XcAZEt3gXft3@3WrcOt55n9trQO1r3tbKPu@v7mvvOOz5nm3zujE6UDkLfWo0Mt@6QfP9w2XUXfHf9vV67ctY6GIDM5m7rXqZDUmcJu7xR7/52qfQX61f8/dW3qd8bdQBubb8rOX/BW2/TSkv@fc/iPGZstxjvLQ5H4z74jNsehlN@J2zuYOgb79v5yLOyu3adxtXd61ifjWCl2iIdp89YzmZ08Vp/GXGPb8mGNF4Abd9nuHqxT@W5qtvsPrd3/o6PLXbu7uKOxOc8dJDqzvIZhHatzheckevELDfbWiLZ7x1Dn5o7I581ap21EmerOF955rNVnW19bLNErbfdYbRB1px163Dcnehb5dp0a@fHdIblHOSvzk6w8OXgy0zO5ji3JY@khdHuEDP8Iffi77bu1Nx@jHziyufrcu8m2tulw73jMPb5upU/ketSJNOX1jmI0elbffvtpJwq1ln4WPn34Zo5a3d/rXv8jrgO@5bO@v0/Xp0woLVUPJJP@s6MouBionNu/Czk9mdeWDkfLMdzd/J9L@Hqjl8pjK7NtmX@Z5B1f@pF5wS0pPcR91l9XvYWY84qbuW14950HcQ7R2N3XnzC9sb3Lo635EhLbrV12GPKQxxbrbcc2tzfnE/XKT3j9K75PCnUaYGWLb9DdlebXW6/xlvKd50/1hHkMC2@6L4Bp@aIrW@55Vx5FGxgsJC2A5FZXTzSbtZyGSCdO7AlK@A0jO@rmxUhRt0eKCSArS6od8UpA4BW8UBvLHAb7uU@W0YozLBxIzJjmZacShFxZBV3C7iy@@Feow25kALw2SI@TtyMAINQxwUOufsRpLsICfa4A3UmbJhZBp/1luy2Vc6/OdylU3@3oLB4P3LX7RcVe62T2@UYR9yRXdzPvj75Hz7mXM2dN0xfINancRWMBPfkb4kbQxQ4XysTccSa1QEsh426YCJswY6MPnYO73JOddxb7pAXsIk6RD5ad8RLGyOMtYYizScPPtbhrDhE/uc29kIiUZV90tXI3@mjLu6BnMvBp9gahVQQyvb61Ppb@n2jLIvPHIVCLIIYoX89n3C@RylBcYq1Ns/L4@QvQJVQbuFUhP/22bBdgSBWYS1yu8R3MppWVnJfIPQlsCQ8Im@iSDQvfGhtsF593sjMDqbfR62MXj4jiQEZDLmIXNM/nPbt0C3jGid4Uw7Y6pXnEttuasEMunPd5RfxdVBLCGTxJbOAJrxrG3JtjuKU3SggeDl0nSig7yADkyMCPXU5wuvXd2Hro31L7fMXP43bUe4p8zj/qgvjjAzXztEuJazgEwE3pQTNt1VwBwA1q4rHPch/9rMNFMSpCjwqb9bRqByH@I1K7oiRg4Hl4pq9wHJwygK0k6CgleuNR9V9kB6QICwhXFvZBBYdQyMNGbbMVWCsibr6KpLE8yO1tpkKDFDEsfHogHNQHD7ITUnidDwHdFxKChVeHRuGA6LTW1rMNrKe8wAzdnW49wYzKHeWJWJ6fOrm04FReMNDPGCJ5/PbsbUXNwEcsVeDAhDuOE@rHJngOw3KgBAwA8L2VdJZnRYFlgZ2gOdxKY5eYihGoaE4F@S05ZtSXClnjLfC2lV58OL4J30GbdqA8CUNKBTkly9yTvfj1oYoqJigJexsoqKV1o3VExBzZuR7Xu/jyq@aDuBGEila9wpCbsE/uSklIIB8BRFlNL0ODyu/JtqnyC/jpgh/MZYt7OrW8z7s0JTyDePt5ZAuabO/astkCOfp1oeYMoQYoK7P@BmwcqJVpGpbEnCiyBvlvba4NfCXeahlj8ClOq2cRAKQ4AgIYV5kYn1JNDgOwKoWeaVgCnwaQZH2yopsUcRssvgDSXfZZj6AdD6YpoVI42wMSxQpn3OhqVj2EqFa/NU6FinNvOOnEJHkgp0b3YudGxsNCrGnsnlXOav0IbqYIi8mkmrYOwBYxUOWoTjY8CfaCM2XMZ7uhNwYZN7kW7Nx8NluQx2hgXHGBEqvZc3P38ajE8KInTY@LarYOm0wEK44v/JIOgf69rtG00TrjFJBPSssiEhONA1crPUyDJnF4L0HqreLaxCRATUXY3AEJN8QWVLKCzZAukjCa3CfFX9QYj4XMGwGqom1RNv2SfG@lXF1vSz4ZW9rfFJiRIhc6@DO33A2O@YmE5iCQu8ffl18V3H@eyEYQWncPy5Lvl1hycBv3@VreXMxDW2C2@sfxkOsSjdsapUTK6L3lqMPsFABBb4jdgXidUgBAhWLNv1wo3Ihk70inng9XmHDbzprlV@TZbZhFUzSMYakRc5O4F6@lTwQPQLCa4jb4vocEPWZvUlP1k4qUSBJO0yqcrQVBanTqkKCiBRR/Vq2zsboBgEBQqZOJ0W2DX6VC9sUN9aRQvQxQbP27S9sIedWZBBUmO4QbG/OH5zc5CM1UPdHuejDtacitRaSg@ip8waYfClYhbDX@bRNTs7OGuAprSFShuTW@QTiA3BI7GF2migOs9f6qHEOWCauyQ5MAqi@ALurFYJ1Xy5pbTlaTLwFIU4ekTqVlu9nB9ZVIBc2FvCh/JNN3HqwWRcBXwTPw6bKiMcRiqzP1EXSug3ra9Ymb@x97t0r38lnE33W1L/KJfxNoKl98yqR2IBvXE2bfaUyJTA8XhyVS5av0tXyK0Bmw9JSGCxKIPiMVU6oHVPlyVBQ8Gzb3@38I1VEXGvBZ7bIfj4PrsERkzsXYesvkKclOdEXOBEOMwmacuHNMdE8cgsq4PSJ8vnasm8sBxfoGFIVyh/jFJ46ESve@BvOyvjELD8kZ06NKYGY7A@EpJRmdAM4d/umUaiKD7x4J9ejiEt9FhtT8qWjR0VB//Pxhmdr@ByVh2AJzMXy31ea6TVCVv49BA7ApCiedSkDdgI0Gm6xYNVzfaLBmxT80iVAuW6jK3YFgxR3oiygqYjKtTg7Hq9Gm3ElGEPzGHw2xqribUxIOZogAcYHC@qkhNBJ1tkmM@3xXIMtk1SgVz6cI1DK4FyRW7JL0YPxAILKKZdQ4jGzriJGk5OYtViV1VJLwJUIG3ZKF6lfN3kGhdduMz8APbLZbz1bdCrZ9UibMNSWtp1DjQ1tXfMkN1zykWW/HLJMy2g3RB@Eu@MWFtzLhTfugIgz1QmFdhFlslrx6CH2oSz4vNWYYicNesDMtFDDUq2vzS50cxSaSj@V/FS3AXUCfgstf@BEyVDQnQs9qm57W5sMWnhgkRqErAd5ukD8UIWO1GMayzGrwnd1m/CW84ct71SGZJsSgYxlGPrheERwvdP7epXEpQTHxsEZWnNCCYNK2BrN4iKE@l@G8rh7KEqzpgCz58/XZUSdcbKbETcjbJ/EiRMeaDOwJY81lTNCToDihDAk@CZoCItFRbHb1lCUo/LJDsxWK3Dknc7PIj@J2gTW037GKGLsT/i4oW7fwfb1kmtcP9njWiMBeTu9RmRQ66oz7CuLlMUDLrqRCShTCvw7uN62N8XoAzWKe2V4RQpvwqMMhsiIXNt1CFho8gbPVQfyoS7ZdsF1RdYudARBVJEMOzQc9o4kK1Y9ytgjS0HGKote9EuIcEhJN1VdXePgqZpcp60DKWqX0WpwEMueJLA1KTkkt@gBRf2HVfZ9HzU1kydDzfU5LRgoEacbAc9Vt8uZJmm61AqX/i6JUoXSh@i@lFbui62kGusUD76vH35uYop27PQ7gKk2s4a4SZIupDIuoDk9Z9natWCxDW2/@AN@UbgssinBICCcyLQBMeZOoidxZDJn6/zXVUstmxVyDXaS4MWirtRl0C918jiioU3zfJQyEejBjWxoLE@C9m9z8OVDCER1SLMfGOLdAkTFeokqwT8h@QN@tCUajdbPjryBlvNLVcvkvaTjDbIZXWIHz9aPdAUododsRKMGfB3XM2R0qhYJUe2zZURaJmJdAW1Va5eYOO17KBOtRvXzODQpGxVKFccmVbBU5Nre1OjCq2E5SVJ4kjNRkxiizLvZ8nZRaW3z4pzXPE/SbDOHKo80tVcyIFejdS9tTU5HXicVE@cAFO1c27hK2jUOCWK0GcNfy5Ks8Cn7aWssnmLNaisgL@fXhbF2ZSKVPQQvVFv6VeBdTWtHc7xC42P0/xJqkNmvD2fctPPAoghkUh3gtC7x@F83SXQ/lz/UsU2i4qabX8YWG3kXfPiStBCtdHFmWob8AW6vuYwxbBtAM2d2y6zBpEjspJBMU3dqXDTJAqmc8OEU1RrsMBZ8TO8T4wx1k3qpBvUHBMkAIkpgVOBIxFx/7WhOF@7Wa2YaGUIGBEIJxpgZUCfecMNBlIV0MGpIa13ZMtFaKEPxWLWudVoBiFbH8N1h36nxmE4NbhBtVKZpkCA9FDGWkIxZ7eAsnTrOiv4eeuwKLooZ4HshsUY6sSlFWZ1n34ijIjXTqaoYXhNE4KWUSHLwZCGPs7RoGlitLUHYrFx4wyRrN5PZPr5@H2EASwlSgP@lMOco7FDQqUvKglBQDHoDeZFXCXnCGPy6iyFwbuuKicpDXV5/5LBKKxaxh52AveWUWYayjH1D@ASfW6OSonYoam7R3ruiLJKkXee8ohIh1pvVglvmBOm0Wt/BEgy15o7eZrh35/vlmNvP/ybsDvGv7F6KS8LMoMf7FQUQ6CTvtZ59KQt0yqaAimR@qK3aUh4K2JZ/UOQK3kpN6nkw2xtqPJT8TlWUyb/knaKrxYdooyzu7VC7XTnbZWZgkLIM1cC2WuxVA9AkNCEHLZD4Co6XC2pfqKUka8UU6gSXceXuiQ7N/UdNJ3c383xSp9Rq4CCdHAoOW8VS/ALDjz2hejNcL0Fw36GjJ0iKxNY8Hj8AQtaVk3VrSqGQ4h1rRz1mkvG2g9ZFvQou@wbKojNBFeItQDhBAmbilOJa0tW2Vt/kDsUW0uHBQQhg9P6wssYphhxZK5QtDZODgxN/2CjvOKTEVXM14l8pkOmzDnXp5gmOqPS9yBa3U5Ki58XF47KAp165Fr@wIWScmNAJ4y8XhSphCKUzElSDA2vy1QBzDQ5NhhLKFf9QopYpHsFSqp5kNCdRsVfrftvgacrWVKhR6k30Cya16gk/xzDHNcxuKzcdCE8ARrqlpWwDUtfXzamsS9WuPtWryBuGIAeoiAVSWjJZ@PoGEhbgS6OFI9FMMbxccbfv23QUpWAIUKm0QqSfKm4J9v2JRDCZ@sHvJgT1TZFcbiScsM1lLRgGb76QDLklTwuZR9HXmha09kOm84Ky7c/ZCgJgYt2L1z9NBtZuAo84UhscX/@4wrY@mtu7NR1a4sbZXqci5Dp/UY6ICgzOWqGsY4dh8VnCMeKdeuVVEAYVRnyw9WFJT2aiZUI10oEAzgacUFkwKxvprh8XRXqBSQ95R3Q21Jx@0lDsmRy9kUiJDN/ITiX4IAyn2oAOxZxUNHEDOyqnQL1n0jzBxo0BZj@xq5j4ZGo1EVmTefSTlBqzuDDr4ECyjYUg3KcvBjZC4SWEJQJe/975hJoeXnNJu9rV3jhUk@cQZkz0uRkClSy1F0vi9tUqvQhOhsR3lrqa9BUFBepUyAr6BQr9h3jabtqQc8y0wRarD68sC5lUY5b@rlVI6kRpmjH6OdjulC3USmZRc9rcimKU9VMo1i3dopxBbVmc/bgeLkgC/tt0i8mjLv6BOoBzIFXDFEVCdcPwLYVT0DGuFmtVwaCiTZS3ux4d2b1FMf4YKrXiecrsGfLOcQkrzo08zxRpHCYyLHEJuAVH@PRB4Anb7PdaNAEcJfls@jXMN3RVOpUmDl5kjtKccr6F/oVURoswhohwa6vuDcu6uLeGn7IoUXkrGlQDWJe@0S/AzMGNuKd4oqCvZxsUKH77SmCkKmBHTahRYXbMD62IbxYLef6ZF6pOQFWjsEYobS7UzDJ8ikjZntcgONYFpkQoTCduasGUTZoOiyJL7jIzTQIVRxTpAHpm3NOkKWzIW8GD7ZZJ0I8ZACdzlK9JkR3ZFU4bNpUgTg0NmKp@2Z7Q427vUFmG8O2ErH3uaQQWsm3gvFkKvivX35g9FrQuSOqdji3AdaIH0nNBKVxMOswrTKK8m5WVvzUZe@IyTYQh2xiQylagftM2bLjqRF9IYEweToetqXClkeE1sscWR@GyksvNT1xtmpYSGfp@lIzoTNear/N5aJfKqv8JkONqSBgoHALMyL1Q6JQvoyP9E7q3LhgM8fQshgnrmQPJ1NHQqL4PbbCvlF3RCNlfTnX6/iadbS6oTb8SufszdDeTYrH0FAcH2vahuENdzoHdBGSIHKED@sUGQcSY4S4b4lgP4tYQbaL7cjSAwEd3o//SMSjrppH5J1eDP63o0N2uWo4sP@3IUieG/4hoFlHXZt0sfU5zCNZbiZ/lCp9lKXhuSTTXp6gsCaEzpMtdfTRxTlyovBxQyu2N3A2oHNapTHbKVMfqYyfT6KwqjDvNlPJtSNfdl9b0XTtH7PjAVa8tYNV3ZTVemjSs@jNiJNITaqW6fYMg6HCdjRhq3TlhEiKNmBNjWFfoC0g@SKF6LAtfa246iZvTLxSlFWRFiHNPAf1Bbv5@O4hgTMMVrO@mSIvoW@Tupg842vMS5UPH9Lrl3X1brzdMS0dVRe73ElJ0TSdT0rVabVH7kyutW83sRcb1YXfllmPnA6KhKSPLSvONuzqmX/ndSjHHCS@nZm/Y4sqlRamZvWJ0ytfrSKMq6QqFu7nMMzUeiK73CVmwrxvSqkOSSa8zp36tEnDzNU6Pe/fkFidQlIOdxViOXzlvTL1AVVNGF7RoGzW15W4GVek19miBmnDVDiSWsJVbjoYiRxp6hJtJztQni19NxSOOiHL8M4@cL2oCk3KOa5iNSFVE5sCvGPvRQ@/WwRBg9aO0/m1eocxONUkCgUZmDowJtmgEpWmJb9gqD/cQaiePSCu2xYEuKmpXf2S1KX5WWzAIVoPQrk1Zng5smFraAIp@FjNOAjCqb3tygRu0Orl6CESNK2n3zFm999OjZVkuceR1p7lNMzFU3N2@uDuvKW0nWrxXuDa56eDIaI2xQA6eC@ttxy1n711uknjlSN5ocTABhSZs88uGUg/EukTgJDejgcociVtBkG0wJkQ9LC@vx1pcvCUYSShdZkbaDa/MSHoc2bh5izkyAthki1YfDi07SENULpgOSecu6lSK1zJeN@@6@oPUZdz1R4/pRIFitOhQ0MZhyXA33EeKRZ7FhLW4aMYuW03A3njXYCtp146fdWPJuIhruUJlnM@wPrQ@gFxD89m3jEtfDbuHEtdKgvAkP307KKFc0ucqO7XBdCKmyyqt5z9a/A1NxUlx5VsdLFYOt7tYNgjBwva2eFooCIJVMPnHi7vO4AIDeHBf@o/jkKqr01pXya7WCqnpCFfwoxn4YMUBPb/7RjQ5SIQNjLLK87B@JbcEcd459VuutbLFnalM8nA2Z81hCqzu94pZbvpo0mhrLMQ1oKZDSqgqmZyPefNIQccjQso6EppKooWI1BfZuZwEcMDjdJyvPbYfIi9qzdCN1vO2u4Xcqt6QyiC6Tdv/j3x@3ppgVG44dWW8oeCczL6upshCHH/bTbwD8OvXd5gxQqHFTZqpGja/Zaf9j367341zPyh7lOkNiCusNwhaSVzr9Dpag89YjkehIeSJviKsRbJsK6slrKCEbTGLIilqImZdTI6b00YxWLhtYvEvs/0zsivaKEj5di16IhwDaluxIuOx9IwhcXHL7CJCPzeNWH4Y8RrYQeXFtq7QpOnCbFvN5KyUP9JDSQNWUPy8uXf92hHod2fE1r6ZRU2QUzS1XMVrX5Yge0hHGWuXPYknAK4HL9VvG8c75kXiZ05P8cKdsqZH6BfZh5LKzGUZiRF61T2POL5@hl5YfEpXpedkoMnsDO1480QOUkjOFqlrp6XjV@7nHkcUDeZ0JkggnQ1UWzoNNzR@9Sbq02cB6YS60wNRMkwLuNybsRkCqwwogKWbjJ70yA3n7DQ/MTTxdftTxu83rgH2zzJhK@Xdk08/sk5GGyN1OjgZMkfGZ3V0XBD9XkXXWUqC8/rOI8kmwk8kHQEbk@bk7aTFDFoxgFnDDMVYpP0Zr1dKEeoJPy3O9kSfdjViKhVXZnYyQxLPXElDfwaUEGnHzZkuQHhchBsuilv/USW6R6SsSaSpFh/nDrVOHBjPF9IAvd6MWKS/b@l9eOL5ck8EBCLcs0VlbxgN6aRDUnsow6ZmgIwWFYK5x3aodWHYQxcN0SSHcFvw2iXkCjcT6jxLyo2xxSc1OcT68ztdmco71WfXGfnkdqF@U328Q8ZxO@F81hl@rSHj/GMBdcTeWcvoCGZV/MAtW0CP@5XeHK31cvVva7A1zuNJekJgvrrCAMZDVeia8Hi9yswlc2xFLGEyhhv91rmlvFJHnq7yvbtZPbgM9E4Vz4PL6qcvNQXuXg8WeL1t6IG7nzZPWc64@x/quS32c6UkQ05cFHVL1pv1Qu82iKM7DTQRJWYYxdB5D@/DORha5dH6bGbjeJ4hmLeeFJaeoEz2Lb8K9tb9RIC5SIL6p1MmlbkRmT2ZfGiRqifplFUKiO2sIqaDjFoLegnlXa8ht50MlJXHKdN53BAsNpJfN@q8LlqinU/GZvZLhgXIaboEMk/NXm5SS/u3cZ4nqiW9b5R2luhT5M1krfpBRRk@Wem4GWdpSnTmtWasxbeeKTNhVmFFqf@jBhz3BP3gclNgmyEN6eOBUrBSVlNGXlfdmt56k0ALotuS2gzW658eCe@zx5hk/IudGB@cFkzDp4wT@xkLUxZ4xaGT8eLEPHOoLfsnt5TKJjlVZRoVmS0OpCu0z2Q6i8dg0vkQyyerdtsF@Cx9pGw6vqHTRhTliuU/CBG7@9GvHipliamNfMfjQOsxfduR49AzIGLRZVf5uqFTmEFCRMdUu02GtpvsyuOd2hVgRuShrpXyR03Ew9hqOaExKLf0GXAaarrzFYw5Lbc9MomLEQceVdupXmTagmc1J4XoTJB5Qo15svOQji5peCbwOz7UACsS/LHysl2lTLO9x1lExYWUfjMvbhJeLbUfFxpRyXgUrQUs1ALrdStbF7KZRIFxxe28ltX26LIZZ1Ob2SYWJiUHQ@I77lR6E8LdNDIeJUwiFDICxr8fZeBzV9Ji0JRGnO1IlfCTtIdSg6nMh0RvPOQwcP30nrhjKpYZ5tGC1UpzjQc@LGUlU/OQCJA8Q0cb5jIMnqn0I2dIjwUoriPaZjkMuD6ZYrssaoW9x@14slFlQHS6Czw2zqSqZY9NcuC7rnRwZwgHLOUi8dwHiQGYHoXKgFM6e1wzgVOjA8@iwJ9KP4M0EEhN5h2L3zI51bGNf3R/TJoBM6bTc67WwNcaYZRrljPw6IFIgt@MereQIIWwitlT@qlARyjztETIvBEPWaxuQLmUHNdTiMkMzQD9yLU3k/EsL9w0yrnAmBkSVhYBcTsa0/SsUaUw899htrY8wd7DXczy0LUpZoBKTWbTGEUrRK8R2WSu7LhgQt3LjVTtgQ1OnjJkeKj@IMdDXf7oMuR1qpOBw70BpBNub4nGw9ROvPGrYOFIp99JRDnHtdejipp@Mg@Ij8gcAVWED56i5hqyp2Yhv@6BSVerviUg4QAzCxthC@PNNnJcO5G10b3hkWZXGDMXmSDPYVBsX1ffeHBEuzWypYX1rAZkewLg7QkAUTi3e0R8KN1Aq4HuzGGHAKTMnI4bt0xLqNaphvt5BB488uQk7zSkY61fo2NnWMV4MvZ0O0fk6R3RnHtua6eLuvYNfHM/TFWmEE5MwAT0@AYtO3JhGneelj335@7T9ssEqGOkrQtEY9WtjyndhM4eLNssj5rbQC1K9@bWPAYjneEe7U9bURorx1MoPYYuauhXnvfEgdAnqcbgqgxGfhpF9zU@1NNRyPDfrM0816E9EZhxR1d0n3mTTtqioHnh0sVEPZAjQ7mmPYN1nMi76qcunXpFZPely8Yr/cwZmuM/emw0a5uXbhCRUOSLyvA1joi@Y1fc0aSFTXvPJZAQ1oK5qjzXYJnfg6hzIth19x0P@HCDgB9UM7@PyHnTxKyQ28jvrXLzKBWPFFdS4w4rtdxshlf4iRrpmfPG4EChON70in4uzGnbkzN5HO/knZwOJtS4NrnU60xEMu6kfqp9VpNtOtVfjxvMqhqeUou9UkkbyXkHMgBhEb3gM5hw0eszQrOQHrzT8xqDHTulcsijC3T7KJ8bZZnHFlNCVqfMeGuRbOnpPnWGOi7TNUbo0WJWC4qH9iOIikEZTFJCrNAZdgmDwzw8FdOFFF99rVCfjh/JgMSsrQHsSlfT06AyF2OMaDt0RpTQFKfHT8cpHwv8pzt@nVFYJbqerkHvPBeQsXymLTIE0Or@fo/gcE/IPMqEsvM/hthWvadBMACK8du2rLIEG@Hx7/RNSnBuKbTDrigJPAajPfwvT/1hOs44oUefNaG3fzSWmWAIKLW8MCXuc30imzzTAkdrUYcnZm1aOkNOupHWvcwu/EhnjhSdZ1Upg7fMD3phNr2q1XlUVPp8qzztO3XTpCX7gEfTvGhuwqX7@cdjHDIRdeoJvdcyZ89a2Iq3wPt5uAReKxnxm@IbViaDoSFXaIDMtGs/i6P/bc9/6hZIm8v6ukxVYARDGfxmBEsGBfV7sk37CQwOsBpvZuebO@3N9AsSrXXLyGQyXXn60HrIXzP@x/NZ@BwLrj0psdHah2Rkw/s9cGD35XljCsu99zORi8OzC6BuBFflbdJTLZhNk6bUDY1c@1sv@kkV0Wue9@ufaXxOk/V8HAdcinc02qdhjIjTlg/JUdKQewW6dEi0H2PQkSMw4hBYsC4Jydv3pll9GZjnZ3hZ7STJHsPUQKEZAuXni5kodsPdWIjs8E2E4elX5hh5JlpVxnEtn@bOCUR/68ICjxJ5Y7t4IswbHe9WNEva3EYEFTZ@3gR1ys7zD6wGlqixnkaq3YGmrt1JAzHqrqk3nK/9YABNFkcjMgSH4ekeznaWYOI2IdGMSGrinFLvg9lgMPeYj/bwE0/TNbR4@vgOfBw/rsQ9kCT3Ay2clppMcwIpOQvwVAJHJLh5Nx/61hG0MIaRHjY/o4HJXKYs6/FF7ceXrTXT9KZ2HnGkxpIQ0vuekYJ5pJyDNN4cUT8A2Brgp6yDacc90TyMLQGxnjO/nskIc3S0Zuw7k5rdX1pwmCkL0uP3pPtTHoCj@OA1AbR1p241qSyYevXDbdpq@LZR8QDCcTCyNDqPD3OZPGzBZLQ@bV3vITMQZd0hOfysKBegHV3N6ntsvh8ThKLhyXvaYlQmAOYhHKILIF7HEmQgaLsN1rK/Sv95hhG3X1IZUGyiDoHKGIwNDwlsP/4Aj4j8fZQH6nkSjMFmwFLaxniKZnqgyeWYROYJ9y/RCc/abTmjBxlNJzJPhkj@///5Fw). (Including all 29,903 characters here would cause this to exceed a StackExchange maximum size.)

Because you can use any 4 distinct characters you want, it's acceptable to use, for example, lower-case instead of upper-case, or to use T instead of U, or to use 0123 instead of ACGU, or even to output the complementary strand (with A and U switched, and C and G switched).

### Restrictions

Standard loopholes are prohibited as usual. In particular, it's not allowed to retrieve information online or from any source other than your program. You also can't use any built-in which yields genomic data or protein data (these would generally retrieve data from the Internet so they wouldn't be allowed anyway, but some languages may have this facility built in internally; use of such functionality is prohibited whether implemented internally or externally).

### Verifying Your Program

I've set up a way to check that your program's output is correct. Just copy and paste your program's output into the argument in [this verification program on TIO](https://tio.run/##jZ1trx3XcaW/81ecOHBIWi@RnAEGiCwDhRq5ECDIAEIq88HRB5q8pC5MXWouSceesfPTRzm917NqN0XKGInkPfecPt27965dL6tWVT/95MXTpz/88Le3d09fvn12c/nV6zfPXt7@7tNvf/3gnfduX/34rfvbuxfHew/@9tnN89u7m8vXX/3mq6@/@pf86vKz6I6Iqr7@7Mjszszj94i8fnB9rb/Xz7Oi8/p/Xz9cL69fOn4/Disdcn2pD67/1/Ezr2/neplx/Xs9oo6XeXxw/VnHRdcQjuvp5fra9dQVxzjiODDWcI53r8ccI1jn02mPb6zhH5/mceX1Wa7RHn@Oyx1fitNRtUYYx0Ghm70efb1YHV88bvA6Ca3j180dhx0jifX1NZY4Pj2OPn72Gutx9uvBxyDWYNerY4Q6dWp8FevPcRtreMd9rPOGxrnW4xjNMU1M5DFtxyDWtMQac67rHgPQ8hwrcIz@mKE1C@vmj9Efw6rQmI5DjxMf3zpu8Pj3GEetM9e66WPGSvO9LhS97nZN83FXx5B63dC6bq3p8qStE9YxvEMUDtnxHeSx4Jol/dG0r9Ou9V/zskZw/cL1PMfdHp8mi7kOOS6wZOOYE8328SWm6zhszWutOdT6afGOiV8jXiupm9Tgj6EdC6Nl7Vqv15CPq1@vsuYgJMqa3mM8a4NIFteA19WPW401D2s@l9hrQdfWWpeVfKy7XpdZ11zbZ8km563SjtJGyDVXJcGNtUmOPww71oDXXR/Ha1WWtBYCILFZt7UO0yaJJQndfFHfPlYp9Eb7iOtbx6IeX9QGWHN7jGTpC766Fi005cd1GuVRZblFeNfksDXWiZdwW8Owy9cOq7UxdMV1dU65pGyNXbuxdffa1ktGkFItkbbTISxLZjR4zb@EOMu3ZEEqT4CW7xBcHexduVTVWuxcam/pO04brNy6i7UlDuWhjRRrLy@B0KrF0gVLyLVjmptNTZHkd21D75q1Rw5p1DxrJpasonylmZesam/rtMkUpb62NqMFMmpJtzbHuhNdVapNt7b0mPawlIP01ZITJLzZ@BKTJXPs25BG0sRodbAZPsk6@LittWvWepR0Ykvna7jrJtLLpc3dZTN26LqWPpHqkiXTRWMpiNLua119raSUKtIZ6Fjp92LM7LV1f6l7PLa4NnuH9vr6F62OGdBcyh5JJx17RlawEdFaanxJyFqf2mZl6WApnnUnx3UxV2v7hcxoW2xT4r8EMtZPHbSUgKZ0nWKdK5eWXZNRSyrWzGvFvejaiGsfldV5cIbOHt3bKN6QIg2p1dRmH1Eu7FhrvqXQar2zdLp26RJOr5r3k0ydJqhZ8rXJ1mhnldPHeEm51tLH2oJspkYXrSug1GyxdZU1nS2NggwUEpJWIBKrZY@0mtEMA09nbdiQFLAbyveVyYxgo9YayCTgWy2jnjFKGQeoZQ/0xcBvQ72sc0sI5TP0qBGJsURLSiWwOJKKdQuosvViHaMFWSYFx6cD@1ijZuQwyOtYhkPqvuTSLQuJ77E21BJhu5lh5zP2lK1llfJPNndo169bkFlcL7nr9EHBWmvnZtjGYXckF@u1xyf9w2mWqln7DdGXE@vd2DJGcvekb7EbhRVYulYiYotVrQ0YNhuxjIl8C1akdNpa/i77VNs9pQ45gEXUJvLWWls8tDDysdquSHLmQsfanAWbyH/Wwi6TiFVlnTQa6Tudatk9POew8QmWRiYVD6WzvWt9ldxXlGRxzpIpRCKwEfp16YSlexQSBLtYc7O1PEp@GaiQlxsoFfl/vWXYqkAuViAtUrvYdyKaVFSyLiDvS86S/BFpE1mi2uZDc4P06nwlMVtu@jpVS@ilMyYwIIIhFpFqekdprxVa09j2E7woy7HVkUslptVU4zPoznWXh8XXRg15II0uqcZpQrumXa6erVhhNYoT3Gy6HCugaxCBSRHhPWXYwuvjNbD21l5T7f03ehq1o9hT4rH0qwbGHinGztYOBaz4J3LcFBIkV4vxO3BQZ1bRuMvlX/LTiSuIUpXzqLhZWyNmO4zeiIkdEXJ8YKm4ZC2QHJSyHNoao6CZyx6NqvsgPCBAaEy4ljIxLNqG9jQk2BJXOWOJ1dWlCBKXHom2zMS4AbI4Fh5tcDaKzQexKUGctmfhHYeCQplX24Zig2j3hiYz7VnX0gBVVnWo98RnUOwsSUT0OGvP2XGj0IbL48GX2Do/bVuzURO4I9ZqQADyO5amVYyM8a3EywAQMALC8sWEs9otMiyJ24E/j0qx9RJCUTINwb4gpg3flOxKOGJcM6xVlQYPtv@Ez3ibFiB0SeIUyuWXLnJMd1JrhRWUTdAU5iyirJXmjdmTI@bIyPfcXseWXjUcwI2MpUjdKx5yyv2TmlIAgpMvI6KIJtvmoaXXBPsE8eWoKczfCEsHcrXmc51seVOKN@xvN5u0CZt9qQ6DIeynNT/YlMLE4Op6jy8BVkzUslRpScKdCOJGaa8Obg3/yzhUs0b4pdqt7EQMkNwRPITalon5JdBgO@BWpcArGVPcp5Irkp5ZgS2ymEkUv5ykNWwjH7h03piGhQjjLAyNFQnvc3lTI9mNhUrhV21bpDBzbT@ZiAkuWLnSvVi5sdB4IdZUFu8IR5XeRMumSIsJpCrWDgcsRkOGXXF8w5O1kTcf9vF0J8TGeOZJvFU9Cn6W266OvIFyxISXHs2cL307Gh0Thu208GlShdZpgXHhgv0rjaR9oKuvMRomakeUMuozw3IRiYkqcRejPQ1FZFFo7wLqzWAMAjKA5kYYbAGJNwSWhOKCHkc6CMKjUJ8x@iCEfDbOsBGoxNZibdM7xesW9qtjR8E7emv7JyFEBMvVNu68w97METeJQAUQep7wdeFdwf7PBmDES@P@UVnS7TJLdvx6D1/TO4NJYBPUXp4QD6EqmaCpEQ6ssN4dtj64hTIo4B0jV3i8Nim4QMGkVW6/UbGQwV4BTxyPVujBNx21Sq9JMtNuFUjSQgwJixydgL0cM7mc6JIj3HZxU1ifDaLOmT3hSVtJjRWYoB0kVTFaC4LUblUiQUCKoH5NW87C6AZxAuSZOpwU2FboVQbWk9xoWwrBxxjN6L2@oIXsW4FBQGG6Q3x7Y/74yUk8EgV0vyAXnVxrKlCrATmwntpvOJM7BIsB7LU/LZM1e6ft4CmswVIOyK39iYuPg0NgD7KTWHGQvdSpyjFgGLgmOjAIoPwC6K5mCNS9GVJbcjSZaAtMnDQieSpN32kF2lkgJzYa50PxJ4vYsd1mDQK8CJyHRZUQly0UUZ@hiwnrelBfozbzxeyt3j3zOfHsWJ829K90Ce@Ma2rd3AokepxvVE0afSUzJWe4PDlKlzSX0mj5CCczQWlJDAYpEHRGKybUiinzZFdQ7lmnr@34Y7KIqNYAz0yB/ZwPrMEWkzsXYOsLSNMSnOgCDoQHmcSbcuLNNtE4cspVQOlj5eeyYd0YNi7AMYQqpD/KITx5ImY80TfslfKOaV5MzDw5pjHERH94SAppSjeAcrduKpmq0YHL3kn1yOKSn0XGFHxp65FR0F9vb3C2BM9RegiUwFgs/@/UTLY9ZMXfheHAmRTE005lgE7gjQ62GKDqMz7B4EkIvsIlnHLdRsbIFQjSqBNFAUlGVKrF0XF5NtKIK8YYmMfOZyKsSt6OCClGk0uA8IGCOijBdBJ1psFMazznYMMgFd4rJ2cLhCI4Z@Sa6FLw4GgAucqTLiHFY2RdSYwkJjFq0UqrTS4BVSLfMCd1MfnrJM4g8Zpp5AdHj2j2mM8UnEp0XeImFLmlTsdQZUFr5zyJDZt4pFkvmyzDMloNwQeD3XELjd/LwBN1gMWpyDGFVhFhsFr2aHvsRVpwa6syxE4YtB0zw0IJStUem1Voz1ZIMv1k8ie7jVMnx6@B5ZdzomBovDsnepTd9rImEbT8gYZqMGA9nqcTxNur0JbaSGPYZsXgXZkGvKX8QctzMkOSTZFAyjQMvVg4In69w/vYmcQmBcfCgRmac0IKg0xY25tFRcjr3xHKxu6BKI2a4phtfd5OI2qPE92UsBn59hM4scPHtSnQko2aShlBJ4BxghmS@ybXEBSLjGKmpSFIR82ZbZjNVmDLO5yvhn4ybBNQT@sZexFlfcLpirx9jm8fO7hG9RM9tjkSgLeVbY8MaF15ht5pkTB5wEk3IgFFSuP@LXc9LW@y0cupkd0Lu1eE8AY8ws4QEZFzuzYBDUye@HOR4/LBLul0wrUF1jZwBEZUlgw5tDvsFZmoWPko@x4zFUSskuiGvwQJh5C0J6urMRaaKol10jyQIHc5XA02YliTjNs6ITkgt@ABWf3tq/S@Hjk1gydFznUrLRAoAac9BJ6V3Q5HmoTpYius8LcJlGIgfYDuFdJKfbGUZGMd4oH35fafE5uiFVv8HZypNLIGuUmULqgyTqA5PGfa0rlgoQ1pvXhyfmG4NLQpuUG4cALTCo9x7mT4JLZMxmwd/zprqWkzQy7xnUR4Malr8jLwl3LiOKyhRXPpKEUiwIM9tKEyPQnYP43BhzchLqpNmvVAYe8aR1Sol6AS9BOUP9yPNEUj4fpZkSeuZZ2haom8p7S8QBajFdiBs@UGXXEUMwdshKOG@1rOZ0jolC2SR9VbliFpGYh1BjSVrW1sYqXvIQy02quvjaGJ2ShTKjtWkwWbjFxam9q78GyYTjIhPMGZoEkEUeKdLHk6qdSWeWHObZxnwmwjh0qPJLlXIiBno3UvaU5ODr1OLCb2AV60Y237VeKusUkgo1XZ/TUtyQyfsJ42x2Iz1sy2wuVl/zoxls5MTGYPwgvZltwZeGfT0tYcrZDoGP0rogaRfXtzjpp2HBgkgQyq4zi1Uzz@tSeIzq3yizy2QVTUdPLhyGJC7wIPb4IWrJUGZ6SliB/A9pJhlN22wmlmz3YYNahJEjsoJNLUndovqokCyZxwcpJqie9QJnxU9ibjFHmT2KEG@QcIyThEpMDIwBGIOf@awzltsFvPmWFkABk8EFIw9plx6oQb9mAQYSIdiBrUWme2DLQGzFA0VrRznWYAwtWx@26z79C4DKeO3yDYKAzTQEHaXkSZQlJGtcfP0q5jr@h94LGVcJHNwL@XJ5ZQJ3pSUWbnWTeiqAjNtKtiBC8xIuBSCiTZeJKQjVmaNI1brSWB2KxYuAdJ1mpOZLvx@t6AASglngL4L4k5W2Gbgpy8pCQIBkXBN5AW2ZmQTYxBrzsZAubWzpgoPZTh@YcOq7CiIXtYCVhbVhhlCNPYewCf8c/NUZmk9kDU3KK1dwyzSJR27fMYlgi23qgW2DI7SLvV/A6moMg15/Btint3vB@2ubn175jdwv6F1UswJMQMeDx3UgCCzsS95rM3aYGctClOxUR@sK3SVB4S2KZ/kOQaf2tyUluDWd5g48Hkd6iiSH4H7yRdTT6EG2Vybw60mzF7O4wMFFSWIhuYZovtbACchMTkwAUSXsH2ckLtMLWkZM2Ygp3gNK7UPdYhuf9h00ndVW2dlJNqteMgnhwMDktFk/zChy9rQtVmOF8C4T4Hjq7xpAhsjePxAieknTlpl6YEDCm@0VbUZSQZbVtwXVSr4LTvuLLwTGCFeAkgThCAGTgluTbhapqrb3CHZAvhcKEg5GBkn1BZ@yl2OWauYLYkSA4KTvhhwrxjk2JXjdUIfyVBpnMtr0s3j3GEpe9JNrmdlBQ1L04ehwk8sdO16IUeQMaBCZUwvrggVBFDSJ0RoNo5MCdfBTCrwCGJUAZyRT@EoGWSR6CUyifZmxOp2LO1Pk38adLWZKhh6tXwFwxqxSZ@lt0c5zAzzdy0IVwEMMItTWXaIXV@3ZhKO1Xt7FPsjLzdEOgAMWSBSS0ZLNx1A2MWwEuHC0egOcnwcMbduq@nomgShjgqMaUQU081agn0fZNEEJk4@e8GBHWloVz2UDhBm8NcMATeeCERcoqeNmAeSV9zWuDaF5HONsqWP0crEICxddten4oMzN3EPWJL9fjx8c4I0/xobm/NaVESV472cjJCzvMH6YhhgYFZy5TlyOGg@Exh2eOt2OlVPAwyjOhg88MmPKkaLhOskRwXwNGAAyoTZiUjmXFSUYQXiHQRdwzPhpzTKQxFnonRE4qUwPAe2qkIH5jhyTbAQzEmNZy4Ah2VUiDfU1M8wcKVHczcZFch8ROpRQ3JmsgjN6XUPosTszYOBNtICMR96mJAI2ReBrCEwOvPHU@o6GEXl6SzXemFgzW5FEKVgT4XQ8CSJfdiSlzvXKUnwcGQ8M5QVZMuEUCgDoXMoG9coffI01bTdjnLSBtoserwwrSQmmxMU9/VMkk5VppijNwKNnPSFiolM6l5ytyCZJT5UzDWTd0inUFuWZh9OR8ulwT/r6daTBq10Q/kARwDKRsmKzJQNwhfkzjFO0bVIq1KGMRwE6XtVo2O5N6kGJ@GTK1wnjB6Br2znMIa5UacZ4h0FCY0LGEJqAVb@KmDQBOm0e82aQJ3lOAzqdcw3pARU6lUo@AF5ijMCcdb8F8IZTQJZRcRbK1VvWFaF/eW4FMmJSpuhYNqB9apb/gLIHNgI64prmHQx5YNEhTnuhIQqRhnR0Wow8LMET@4Ir5ZJGTrZw5UnoCsRiCNQNoM1MgyeIpA2axdIFjmBU6KUD6dsKnGp0zCdFAUSXKGkWkCqFFEQx2Az4x6qikKK@JW/MF0ySTejxEAB3OkrwmRbdllThM0FSNODg03VfWyWQOPu7xDaRnMtwOy9L6nEFiebeLOG6XgWjP@ROyRoHZCUt@0bcFdx3pAPZcrhYqZCvMYJFHazczKc07GmjgMEyHIFgaosjGuflI2bHfVgb48gTJ4WDloTQxWOjS8hPaYwiicVnK6eZOrDdOSIoPfD5MRnmmb87V0HtylMOu/xpFjNAQMJA5xzIi9YOiEh5FD/ZN3b14wPsTms9hNaPccmEgdDo3y@8AGvVPZMRwh68uKnLq/mso2J9Qqd4rc9Rm6m5pksfgUyx1Iy4fsDnk5G3YDkAPkyDugXqwgRJQR7rAglvkgLg3RIrouRw0IvHV7@F/aBmHeNDT/idXAT2N46C5XDVuWUzmy2ImDfwxpFlJXz7yZ@jzFIUhvjP0MZ/hMS0Fzi6LZ3kVhSgiVIRmu6qOIs0aFSsvhSrm8kbvBKwd1CoOdEtUy@9jBNDyrGMSdYkrpNqjrrktL6q4dI@bowFatLc6q78psvCnSMOvPHiOWHlMr1u1uBEGFa/WQodqVEwYhphCzRhjaGfrAJS@oUFmmhbc5NzmBm8MvGKUxnhUmzjUF1Ae5@HuvIIQxNVcwv5skLaRvgbs9dcDDPQ9BPlRMt0veXbe1a8M0dWRVpH5XQAqvadGUNFazLaJPsVK71MxapJwfdlVu2HZuR3RgyqFlTfGNqzoqd/rdTDHbCU@nem9Y4sKpRbGZPWNUyseuSCMr6QyFq7mMMyUaiKr3GrCgdzWkWYcEk55ndn2bJeDia5Qe9@7OLQ6gSAc7ijEdP2a/0fUCVk3Yu6BE215Tmu5mp2pqjd1aIGqwahsSU9jCJUdFkmMKeuQ3E5ypTha9OhmPUUSk47d4zP4iJ1CTznEOMyGpCsgs8BX7ftTQu3RwALA4Ma3PxSuk2ckmiSCQ0MxxY8a3SAilUxKfoFVu7iGvnThiSrFNDnRSUat6otVO8jPShEF8NQDt6EnLU4ENUksZQFDPYsRJDozy2@5c4AKtnFh9AES1K0nXzJm9d6rRMi0XO7Kr01ymOTZU2F1vu1u7KK1ruHg7cW1w08aR1hplghw4F9KbtluO3jNcJLHTkXzR5GAMCkXYxpftSm0n1ikCB7nTGiiMkbgUBNoGbUJUw7LjeqTFyVuMkYjSYWQkXfBKj6SNkZWLt@gjIwebaNHsw6JkB2qI0gWVA9K5inoyxW0ar4t3nf2B6lKu@qPGtIaBYm/RpiDth02E24N9TLLIvZiQFifNWGWzCVgbrxpoJeXao2ddWFJO4pquENPOp5gfSh/wXAfms24pp74SdA8mrpkEg5Oc6nZgQjmlzyhzcoNTiThVVlN6fuLi98BU7BRnvlXBYuZwuoqlx0MwsT1NnpYXBMAqN/mkxZ1ncIIBf7B3@I/iEKsrp7QuJrpqM6Qqh7iCHp2GD2YcUPPbu0WTjcSggcOscj@sM@UWI843K87pWjNbXJlKJw9Hc@YcToLV9V4jlj11NFNoa1@IMcCmg0qoLJmUj3HzoYKWW4SEeSQUlQwXYqi@0M6lJHAH3E7H8dpG@wHyhq05cKP5vOlqIZeqJ6AyHl1P2f@JPl97ThAqF5w6M55AcA5md1XT0EJsf9NFvIXjl7vucNoIDSxu0EzZsDqnnfq9ervzwrkelDWa7g2QK8w3GG9l7FpOraM5@LTl2BAaRJ7hVwxqMVG2mdUiVpDCNplFlhQ2Eb0uarabw0YhWKhtbPEZ2T617BpuFKB8OhddQxzD1TZjRcJj6hlN4kYts4oQ/Vw0YvrhkNfwHZReTPMKDZo2yLbZTI5K@TE1lBRgjRdfu@9d7nIE6t1psdW7Z1Fi5GRNTVfx3IcpyG7SEfa1w5rEHQDbjZfiXMaxt3kQ@BnTk71wpazhEepFentJYeQy7IlhelU9Dzk@Tk0vTD6lqtJ9MuBk5jTt2P1ElkshOttQXXNKOs50P9c4wmgwplPjCUxlA9mWnIIbCr@yx@pTZwHoBLvTDVGmmRbucva0zZCzSoMCULqa1pNuueGYneInmibuan/S@LnbNYD@mSZsprxr8qlH1s5I@0g5FZw0mSPiMzt6VBD1XkHV2aQEa9edDyUbC19D6Rhno6Y4uXPCYhqt2IFpuxmysVD7p71eKESITfw0OdsdfdLZiIrJuNKzkx6SaOaYMPTUoARLWy7OdALC7SJccBHc@omV6BqRMCeRolp0nCvUcuxAub@QGuhlT4tF6vua2odNng/XRAAggj2bVLab0RBO2iSlmzL05Ayg0cJCMPaYNrVODLvpol000SFcFtxWCTPCng517iXlwtjgTEkM0T5/TlWm4k7V2eW0fHK5UO6uPl4h@3Fdg/m0I/xou4z1zgRqi@29Nq0j6FVxcrcsAVmuV9p9tNrTlefSYHOcy5305IF5dIEAlJuqUDXh9noxPZeMsQW2hM4YLvRrx5bSSjn0dKXvXc3qxmV472Tx3LgsTnWpk@DOdmOBXdsGHzhzc/MU5ZSr/4Ge02Q/Z0qmyYmToi7J2r1eqN3G48icApohJU4ziqLyHtyHfVCUysP16emN436G@LyxqbDUBE1n3/BRoLeuJ8KZG0pQniplJjNXArNrOh@apOpOOmGWAmQ7s4ipICPXAl9CcdcuyE0HA2Hm8aTp3G4IFBvKrwt1dhUt1s47o6f3yzQLkNJ0CqQ2mz1cpDbl3/bz3FFtwvuEaWeKPkne6awVJ69omk/GVNyUozQFOrVLM9rkW/eUqUFWQUXJ/8MGLNcEnfxyQ2A9TRqmjgdIwUxZdRnZVXVteGt3Ag2AblNqp7FenmokvM5uYzLtX6zEOPGUYNp9mnZip7YwYYLXKHQiXpSYew6laf/ElmLZTEwV042KyBYFkjGwT013FrfBpPJhJJ@o2mUX@GdTR8qioxtyyoiGuWL6D0TEzNzwq5tKmWJqIe9yO9DYSF/n0HGoGRCw6LSrdF1RKUwjIazjZLsNhqaL7MLtndIZYFrkwa4V80dFxEXbaimhslNu6jPO6UDTOZegzWm47JFOXLQ4cKvanOzFdFtwr@YJIXI6yGyiRm3a@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@4TLodcqT4Yd7AQgnXN4yHA9DO6ONdwYLRVq5dyLMOcYeGypK6sncIH5I5hCohvjgLmrOIbtrFvTrLJB0leqbAjIY4PTChthCe7MeOq6VSFvodvNIoyu0mRuaIM9hkG1vZ994cES6NDLFhXWvBmh7csDTHQCG4ZyuEfGmdAGtGrrThx0AkDTzVNy4ZFpEtZxsuJ9H4MYjm06yd8NUrOUudMxpVlHujF2ZjhF5esdwzt23NaeKOno3fHM9TMR0IawRAQPQ5Rs07ciJadT5lOy5Prc3t18iQB5jyrrwaMy69TalmtDRg2mb4VZzPa4WqXtja26DMZXhbu1PWdEUVpa7ULoN3bChd3reHQcGPplsDKrKzsipULR34UNsHoUEf/fanOc6pDsC0@5oJd2rdqeTNCmotrl0MlEP5JimXJXuwVoO5J31U5VO7CSy69Il4zH1zNM0xz@yLDRtmRdvEJLQ0BcV4asdEXXHzrjDSRs0bT@XQERYE@Yi5rkGTf8eSJ01hF1X3/GADxcI@EE1dX5Ezu4mZoZcD/3eLDe3UnFLcQU1rrBSyU1P8wo/UWNq5rwwKFAgjt29IrcKc9i26Uxux1vzTXYHHWqcm2zydQYiaXcSp2yf2WQ9leq7xg1kVQVPk4tdqZK0J@cVmAYIDekFnUGHi2zvEYqF9OCdrF0YbNsplsM8ukC3D/M5YZa5bTEpZFXKlJcWypae7hNLUMtpukQI3VrMbEHh0H4EUdAog05KkBVyml2C4NAPT8l0eYo7vxawT8uPZIBiluYAZkxV0@ag0hej7NHmwBnDhCY5XX46TnhboD9d8euIwizRdncNaucZwLTlM2wxTQDN7s/9CA7XhNSGTEg7v9PENmI/DYIGULTftmSFKdgQj8/dN0nBuaTQCjuGSeA2GOnmf/PUH7rjlAN6@Fk18PaJYzkdDHFKTS@cFPdSfQKb3NMCRWtShztm9ZR0DjjpQlrXMjvxI545VHSeVaUI3jQ/4IXqqVWNnEdFTZ1vhLt9T950wpLejkdSvGhswqn7eucxDtMRtWITvds0Z/da6BhtgfZzcwm01kTEu4vvoDLTGBpwhQLI6XbtZ3Hkj9b8lLeA2hzm101XBVowhJ3facEyjYJyP9km/QQGG1i1N7PynTvNnu4XBFrtkpGaznTh7kPtJn9J@x/3Z@E8Jly7U2LCtR@QkQXP/cCB7h3nlSEs195XDV0cnF0Oag/hKrxMeqoFvWmmKLUHRo4@54tOoSJ8zaX98tSNz2Gyno9jg0vyjkL7KRjD4qTpQ1KUFOSuBN1USKQfY5BDR6DFIW5BOyUkbZ89xepNwzw/w8tsJ1H2aKaGFzpNoPx8MQPFLrgrE5FtvrEwPP3KGCPPRIuYdlzN2Vw5AemvnVjgUSK7bRdPhNmt412KZkqby4iAwsrPmyBPmfP8A7OBRWqMzZFKV6CparemgBh2V8Vuzpd@MIA6i8MRKYxD8XQPRzuNMXGZkGBGKDWjnCbfB7JBY@4yHu3mJ@6ma9di8@Nz3Mfy40pcA0lwX8DCU1Iz3ZzwlBwFuCuBLRLYvIsPfesQWmjDSA2bn9FAZy5DlrHxovTjy9qcaWpTcx5xpMKSAaR7PyMF8Zh0DtR4Y0S5HcBUAz9FHXQ7zhrOQ1kSIOs58suqaWEOj9aIfU6nZteXBhjmpAWp8dvU/Qo3wJF98JzgtGVO3qoms2Do1Q@3SbPh00LFAwjLxsjU6Hl8mNPkgxbUtNanrGs/ZAagLHNADj8rygloW1ej@m6b78cEwWjY9J40GZUOgPMQDsEFAK9lCjIuaLoM1rS/mPrzaUacPiSmQbGBOggqZWeseEhg@vEHaETo76U4UM@ToA02DZambIynaE4NNLEcncjc4X4HOoOzZprO6EZGlWOZa5pI/vX/fvbgwdNvn9xfXr569fu33//rk9@9vPnt57/87998cfn7v7/Ey5eXm5c3393cvXl9ub27fXP75OXt/7l5dnnz6vLZp/ri/c0fbu5f3/zz6fsP@@FHn3/zxYPbuzeXm/v7V/eXLy@fffHg@t8fXt0@uzz99ubp73/z6v7frid7ltdzPFonevr4weXyf69/L7fPL48ePb386svLw8vDx5c///ly/e3Xl4f/@fDxccyFw67/fX9/vcbzRz/76uuv/@fX/3g5Tvbk6Zub@8vDnz97eHn19s3l1fPrQa@@v751/@Tuxc2n/373s4@vl/qCE3h4n/PGX64//nLc@nuDfLBu57snt3ePjhdP7l88vZ7oGPgvfnH95Q@PH1wHpd9v776/XvnLi@7rF48fHZ//9vNvjquut8Iv0i/KL/r64jj//c3zm/ubu6c3/3xz9@LNt7y7zvzuO/z87vb1mye/v7k7hpqv3t69Yc7XZP7y8jdfrhGv6dPk/WjqvvrjdeJe/uny6u7mOPLtseaX29fXcfzvt7f3N8@OiWPWbv54@@bR5/rlL9cr/Gio1wu/fnP/8ubu0Tw19/Ea5Ax9H7HefHwM8z@@vX15c3l0Purv/u7y6OG/3z28fPmlvv3b06efXKfzdDfnTz75Yr91/so3mhJGfczL@WrXGfrRjfz0ZL30bfz82ceX19@@evvy2eV3N9ffJF6n03783klPc/jLPYdx8T1eZ@bpt/d77j6@PIzrJvhkP4P4urMu@deOz/ePr792fL1/fP@14/u94x/MDPXr27sXS5TXRnx9@flT/X95ft1oh@q@ztGapfj4kh9f6uNLLwF4XyuE9suP384Pv10fflsnXxolDkHKx3/@s17VvOrjVc57Oe@VXv20IPzrtzcfvNcn9zeXu1dvLt8/ub3/j9vXN5dn1@15e/f0zafv3/r7asji@flx@fXRGsGSmX9Y93PW1o/e3r2@fXF38@xxHBJ@lZYvfuqAXAfkTx9Q64D66QN6HdAPv1j7/n3NHw@PAw799qFPc32aP/FprU/rJz7t9WkfFz4k6dHt2s2X28uv3tGKl9uPPpKRwEYcEzmi@tvbb46N/uF7e4TG@ObxN5iZbWgu7yvYjz46xnL5gCG6PDk09bObP141wj9eTdHTh5dDK3x8mQucvnmM72/@/wd0utZVOx8ydmjsq5V7cxXF56/e3r8rjx/P3@uc/fzpT4jfEsGXr28@cJGt3Y770Pc/sDynQZ8n@/E3@wp/ebAX5H1r9eur8H/2gWn3OD7/bFbgfIeffHK5f3t3ub7@7vbuyZt37NTo2f92HsT697DwVylin703mr3d1lc9Ne@qgH/76ut/@s0/ffU/fmwZP7NWX1c5HIYHP/zww1d3h1vyp2OBrv7Ii/sn3z18fTgoh6fw7dVAHC7VdVZvn//pcvvm0//39PnLJy9e//DJ/3ry8uX13@ufpQf@Cw) and run it.

### Other Info

Some facts that may or may not be of help:

1. There are 29,903 bases in the sequence. The counts for the individual bases are:

   - A 8954
   - C 5492
   - G 5863
   - U 9594
2. If you simply code each of the 4 bases in 2 bits, that would get you down to 7476 bytes (plus program overhead), so any competitive answer is likely to be shorter than that.
3. The source for the data can be found at [this web page at NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MN908947); scroll down to ORIGIN. The data is written there in lower-case letters, and 't' is used instead of 'u', apparently because DNA sequencing techniques were used.
4. There are variant strains of SARS-Cov-2 known (the base sequences are slightly different, and the length varies a bit); I believe the one here is the first one sequenced, from Wuhan.
5. Groups of 3 consecutive bases code for particular amino acids, so it might be useful to analyze the data in groups of 3. But there are non-coding areas where the number of bytes isn't necessarily a multiple of 3, so you may not want to just divide the data into groups of 3 starting at the beginning. If it might be useful, you can find more info on the structure of the virus RNA [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7161481/) (but this probably isn't needed).

***Disclaimer:*** I'm not a biologist. If anyone has any corrections or improvements on the underlying biology (or anything else, of course), please let me know!

Happy golfing!

Comment: Mathematica has `ResourceData["Genetic Sequences for the SARS-CoV-2 Coronavirus"]`. It fetches data from the internet, but somebody like me could argue that it's allowed because it's sort of built-in, so I think you should disallow coronavirus genome built-ins here. I get 7846 bytes for Bubblegum with zopfli (probably because the raw storage mode in DEFLATE always stores >=1 byte per source byte, and the other ones have various LZ77 stuff in the Huffman tree, increasing overhead for non-compressible parts, assuming I understand DEFLATE correctly)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Thanks for pointing that out -- I added in something to handle that. The challenge now specifically prohibits any use of built-in genomic data or protein data. This should take care of somebody somehow getting, for instance, a related virus genome and then just compressing the diff.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that somebody has [beaten you to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205873/92901).

Comment: @Dingus  Yes, I just noticed that.  I voted to close the other question as a duplicate.  Posting in the Sandbox for a couple of days first is the recommended procedure, after all, so my challenge has priority.  I've gone ahead and moved it to the main site. (And I think it's better though thought out, and it has a verification program -- plus it benefited from mypronounismonicareinstate's comment about Mathematica built-ins.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector I agree that yours is better thought out. The verification program is a great feature - obviously a bit of  work went into creating it. I'll leave my answer posted pending the outcome of the close vote. Not because I don't support your claim to priority, but for the sake of my own priority in posting the first answer.

Comment: @Dingus -- Thank you!  I have no problem with answers being posted to both challenges as long as they're still open.  (I think the other one should be closed, but I also don't believe in penalizing answerers for problems with a question.)  If I had let it linger in the Sandbox for a month, it would be fair game, but it's only been there for a couple of days, which is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## Pi or Phi?

### Task

Given a positive integer \$n\$ where \$n \geq 10\$ as input, determine whether \$n\$ occurs in the first 100 digits of pi (after the decimal), the first 100 digits of phi, or both.

#### Reference

"The first 100 digits" refers to the 100 digits after the decimal place in each number

First 100 digits of Phi:

```
(1.)6180339887498948482045868343656381177203091798057628621354486227052604628189024497072072041893911374
```

First 100 digits of Pi:

```
(3.)1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

#### Input

- You can assume that the input will appear in the first 100 digits of at least one of the two numbers (pi or phi)
- Input can be taken as a number, string or any other reasonable format
- The input number will have 2 or more digits and won't exceed 100 digits

#### Output

Output should be one of three consistent values:

- One to represent that the number appears in (the first 100 digits of) `Pi` (but not phi)
- Another value to represent that the number appears in (the first 100 digits of) `Phi` (but not pi)
- Another value to represent that the number appears in `Both`

### Examples

**Input**: `113`

**Output**: `Phi` since the substring `113` appears in the first 100 digits of phi, but not in the first 100 digits of pi.

---

**Input**: `793`

**Output**: `Pi` since the substring `793` appears in the first 100 digits of pi, but not in the first 100 digits of phi.

---

**Input**: `84`

**Output**: `Both` since the substring `84` appears both in the first 100 digits of pi and in the first 100 digits of phi.

---

### Test Cases

```
113 -> Phi
793 -> Pi
84 -> Both
618 -> Phi
141 -> Pi
86 -> Both
3398 -> Phi
3993 -> Pi
39 -> Both
374 -> Phi
679 -> Pi
35 -> Both
072 -> Phi
078 -> Pi
117 -> Both
1798057628621 -> Phi
71693993751058209 -> Pi
803 -> Both
811 -> Phi
10 -> Pi
11 -> Both
```

Comment: This seems like mostly a challenge to compute digits of pi or phi, which feels like a chameleon challenge.

Comment: I think at 100 digits I agree with xnor, but if you made the number of digits smaller I would expect some kind of compression to be a better approach. That said, I'm not sure it is then terribly different from other compression based questions since I don't think phi or pi have any exploitable structure. I do think there is a good idea somewhere in here, I'm just not sure this is it.

Answer (score 2):

## Pwning Passwords [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Alice decided to improve the security of her website by [sending first five characters of an SHA-1 hash](https://blog.cloudflare.com/validating-leaked-passwords-with-k-anonymity/) to Bob's Leaked Password Detection Service. However, she made two mistakes that let Eve decode the passwords: sending passwords over HTTP and checking the password after each character of a password is typed. Eve asked you for help in decoding the passwords, however she cannot really program, so needs your help in implementing password cracking algorithm as a computer program or function.

Eve eavesdropped the requests for following hashes from Alice.

```
516B9
379FC
19C2A
9D4E1
08506
F808E
A7F93
5BAA6
```

How could you decode this password? Well, you can brute-force all lowercase letters. In this case the only letter whose hash starts with `516B9` is `p`. The hash of letter `p` is `516B9783FCA517EECBD1D064DA2D165310B19759`.

Knowing that the password starts with `p`, you can brute-force the second character. In this case, the only possible character is `a`. The hash of `pa` is `379FC0D5299A71AC0F171FBB5AFB262829B4E765`

You can continue to brute-force letters one by one to figure out the password was `password` (`5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8`). Well, that was simple.

Not all passwords are that simple however. Consider the following requests:

```
4DC7C
A84FD
467D7
BD79D
12D83
```

First three characters of this password are simple: `rxr` (`467D7856C648A79A096D339A2CE5FC929658967D`).

With the fourth character it gets more complicated. BD79D matches for `rxrf` (`BD79DEC8435B8BA509A25F419F31CC2ACDE2FF0A`) and `rxrp` (`BD79DC20901B11468F8369B5B0D15894F3D96A5E`). There is an ambiguity, but as it turns out, it can be resolved by trying both ways. If you assume the password starts with `rxrp` there is no valid letters to continue with. However, if you assume the password starts with `rxrf`, then it's possible to append `a`, resulting in `rxrfa` (`12D83D3A429CD7D64E9A532C05C2C00C35032A94`), which is a valid solution.

All **passwords will be composed entirely out of lowercase letters**. You can assume all inputs have a solution and there are no inputs that could possibly resolve to multiple passwords (for instance `["4DC7C", "A84FD", "467D7", "BD79D"]` is an invalid input because it can match both `"rxrf"` and `"rxrp`").

There are no case requirements on the input. Your program is allowed to assume the input is lowercase. Your program is allowed to assume the input is uppercase.

The program must not take longer to execute than 24 hours for a 25 characters long password.

It is allowed to use external libraries or language built-in functions for computation of SHA-1 hash.

## Example Input and Output

This is a JSON.

```
[
  {
    "input": [
      "516B9",
      "379FC",
      "19C2A",
      "9D4E1",
      "08506",
      "F808E",
      "A7F93",
      "5BAA6"
    ],
    "output": "password"
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "07C34",
      "593B7",
      "0262F",
      "CED65",
      "23612",
      "4EF76",
      "B7A87"
    ],
    "output": "letmein"
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "84A51",
      "87DDA",
      "83F67",
      "E6FB0",
      "5157D",
      "82CD7",
      "6F655",
      "43426"
    ],
    "output": "codegolf"
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "7A81A",
      "DB3D4",
      "FE05B",
      "E7280",
      "32726",
      "30AE9",
      "2C61A",
      "A9E46",
      "15D98",
      "F780A",
      "3E949",
      "F4BF2",
      "6A5C4",
      "C4554",
      "FA2EA",
      "48A40",
      "5DD7F",
      "5284E",
      "C0B8D",
      "20D59",
      "9184C",
      "32AD9"
    ],
    "output": "onetwothreefourfivesix"
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "84A51",
      "87DDA",
      "26CA7",
      "9D925",
      "08A23",
      "BE075",
      "3179A",
      "5D904",
      "54C70",
      "47790",
      "5D3B5",
      "0E4CE",
      "004C7",
      "EC8A8",
      "131A6",
      "7F47F",
      "41BC6",
      "FCF07",
      "D62BD",
      "DD14F",
      "6A141",
      "EE184",
      "595F8",
      "9D303",
      "BFD36"
    ],
    "output": "correcthorsebatterystaple"
  },
  {
    "input": [],
    "output": ""
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "4DC7C",
      "A84FD",
      "467D7",
      "BD79D",
      "12D83"
    ],
    "output": "rxrfa"
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "4DC7C",
      "A84FD",
      "467D7",
      "BD79D",
      "7B743"
    ],
    "output": "rxrpa"
  }
]
```

Comment: I wonder whether MD5 might be preferred over SHA1 - as in, more likely to exist in the language without having to load external libraries?

Comment: Languages without a hashing builtin or library would have effectively two challenges: implementing the hash and doing the key part of the challenge. There are already challenges for MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81195/implement-sha-256. I see two resolutions to this: 1. not count byte count of the hash; or 2. use a simple hash, such as the digits after the decimal point in the square root of the sum of code points

Comment: You could allow a black-box function as input that computes the SHA256 hash to make this more competitive for languages without builtins.

Answer (score 2):

## Posted at [Baba if you, flag is win](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/206452/68200)

Comment: There are a lot of possible rules (I think a little less than 2^9, as for each X and Y either X is Y or X is not Y, and there are 3*3=9 (X, Y) choices). Is there any documentation on what's the behavior of each rule combination? // i.e., even in this simplified version there are still a lot of fuzzy details on how the rules behaves.

Comment: @user202729 , Thank you for your input. I’ll take out the clause about “no non-core packages” as suggested. In terms on the moves after win, I think the easiest thing will be to say that one can assume the input sequence to end on a winning move. If a longer sequence is given, that’s undefined behaviour and the program can do whatever.

Comment: @user202729 Finally, I admit I'm not certain what is your source of confusion. The rules work just like in the main game (with the caveat of `everything is stop`), and I've specified a lot of tricky cases both in this post and in the accompanying [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/baba). Arguably, the code on GitHub specifies the problem *precisely* (as it is an execution of it). I've also added test cases to allow one to check the behaviour. I'm not sure what else could I do?

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 2):

[Logo Pack LAPACK (Posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206682/logo-pack-lapack)

Comment: The default for [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] is that the exact, constant string must be output, so I suggest no leading spaces allowed. Some languages can't output in certain forms (e.g. printing) without a trailing newline, so I'd say it's okay (instead of "print this logo", I'd suggest saying "output this logo exactly as the following string")

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 2):

## Migrate Try it online! to CommonMark

Try it online! generates old-style MarkDown code blocks which indent all lines with 4 spaces and then optionally precedes the block with a language comment.

Furthermore if the code block can't be parsed by old-style MarkDown (e.g. it has a leading newline, common in Retina answers), then it instead uses a `<pre><code>` block, with HTML escapes for all nonprinting characters.

Your program or function must take a whole TIO post, and change its code block into CommonMark style.

Examples:

```
# [Python 2], 16 bytes

<!-- language-all: lang-python -->

    print "Python 2"

[Try it online!][TIO-kdaf9y51]

[Python 2]: https://docs.python.org/2/
[TIO-kdaf9y51]: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQSkAzFcwUvr/HwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"
```

becomes

````
# [Python 2], 16 bytes

``` python
print "Python 2"
```

[Try it online!][TIO-kdaf9y51]

[Python 2]: https://docs.python.org/2/
[TIO-kdaf9y51]: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQSkAzFcwUvr/HwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"
````

which displays as

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 16 bytes

```
print "Python 2"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQSkAzFcwUvr/HwA)

while

```
# [Retina 0.8.2], 13 bytes

<pre><code>
Retina 0.8.2
</code></pre>

[Try it online!][TIO-kdafdbm1]

[Retina 0.8.2]: https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d
[TIO-kdafdbm1]: https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKwjMUDDQs9Az@v8fAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online"
```

becomes

````
# [Retina 0.8.2], 13 bytes

```

Retina 0.8.2
```

[Try it online!][TIO-kdafdbm1]

[Retina 0.8.2]: https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d
[TIO-kdafdbm1]: https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKwjMUDDQs9Az@v8fAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online"
````

which displays as

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 13 bytes

```
Retina 0.8.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKwjMUDDQs9Az@v8fAA)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 2):

## Where are the traps? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Related: [Trapped Knight Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179195/trapped-knight-sequence)
[The Path Of The Wildebeest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179157/the-path-of-the-wildebeest)

#### Background <sup>Partially copied from my related challenge</sup>

The trapped knight sequence is a finite integer sequence of length 2016, starting from 1, and has the following construction rules:

1. Write a number spiral in the following manner:

```
17 16 15 14 13 ...
18  5  4  3 12 ...
19  6  1  2 11 ...
20  7  8  9 10 ...
21 22 23 24 25 ...
```

2. Place a knight on 1.
3. Move the knight to the grid with the smallest number it can go that has not been visited before, according to the rules of chess (i.e. 2 units vertically and 1 unit horizontally, or vice versa).
4. Repeat until the knight gets stuck.

It is known that the sequence ends at 2084 where the knight is trapped. But here is a twist. Suppose a knight can step back to the previous grid whenever it is stuck, and choose the grid with the next smallest number possible. By doing so, the sequence can be further extended until it is stuck again at 2720. Then, the knight steps back and choose another path, which further extends the sequence until it is stuck again at 3325...

Then, we call these numbers at which the knight is being trapped "traps". So we now know that the first few traps are at 2084, 2720, 3325, ... and it continues to infinity.

#### Challenge

Write a shortest program or function, receiving an integer \$N\$ as input, output the first \$N\$ traps in the extended trapped knight sequence.

#### Values

The first 100 terms of the sequence are as follows.

```
  2084,   2720,   3325,   3753,   7776,   5632,   7411,   8562,  14076,   8469, 
  9231,  22702,  14661,  21710,  21078,  25809,  27112,  24708,  19844,  26943,
 26737,  32449,  31366,  45036,  37853,  37188,  43318,  62095,  67401,  68736,
 70848,  62789,  63223,  69245,  85385,  52467,  71072,  68435,  76611,  84206,
 81869,  70277,  81475,  83776,  70767,  84763,  99029,  82609, 103815,  86102,
 93729, 100614, 108039,  82111,  99935,  85283, 109993, 119856, 119518, 116066, 
109686,  92741, 124770,  92378, 104657, 125102, 107267, 107246, 117089, 117766,
 99295, 121575,  98930, 117390, 123583, 112565, 122080, 111612, 111597,  97349,
105002, 130602, 133509, 153410, 127138, 143952, 153326, 157774, 122534, 136542,
163038, 134778, 140186, 162865, 171044, 159637, 171041, 174368, 184225, 152988
```

#### Winning Criteria

The shortest code of each language wins. Restrictions on standard loopholes apply.

Answer (score 2):

## Convert LifeOnTheEdge to LifeOnTheSlope

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Your task here is to take a LifeOnTheEdge pattern and convert it to LifeOnTheSlope.

A LifeOnTheEdge pattern is composed of these four characters: `|_L` . A pattern corresponds to a certain arrangement of "on" edges in a square grid. The pattern is placed in the grid first with the characters in the cells, and each of the four letters specifies the state of the edges on the left and the bottom of that cell. `|` means the edge on the left is on, `_` means the bottom edge is on, `L` means both of them are on and   means neither of them are on.

For example the following LifeOnTheEdge:

```
|_L
 |
```

translates to:

```
. . . . .
|   |
. ._._. .
  |
. . . . .
```

Your task is however convert it to LifeOnTheSlope. LifeOnTheSlope is a LifeOnTheEdge equivalent but only uses three symbols: `/\` . You should rotate the pattern 45-degree clockwise, for example the above example translates to:

```
/

/\/
  \
```

## Sandbox

I'm not sure if I described the problem clearly. Improvements on the wording and other things?

Comment: Nice challenge! The task is clear, I just think you may specify if and how leading/trailing newlines/spaces are allowed, for example in the example there may be a trailing space. And also.. Are the set of characters strictly fixed? People usually ask for free sets, for example some values [1,2,3,0] instead of `|_L` but since this is [tag:ascii-art] I think it's fine to have a fixed set. Let's see if anyone else has any opinion.

Comment: @AZTECCO For the second question I'm fine with both options. This convertion is a thing that annoys me in my CA exploration.

Answer (score 2):

## Source Code Byte Frequency - [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/209319/source-code-byte-frequency)

Changes from the original idea:

- Without the requirement of fixed representation of the result (percentage and trimming).
- With constraint: source code must be at least 1 byte long
- Changed from character to byte, plus removing the constraint of SBCS languages only.

Comment: This may qualify for the [tag:quine] tag but I'm not so sure about that

Comment: Trimming the output may be difficult for some languages, maybe you could also allow fractions, or require that the output is only accurate to x decimal places? Something to consider when writing a challenge is if a rule actually contributes to the problem or is just an accessory of sorts (here I think the main problem is finding the proportions, and rounding is an accessory)

Comment: @golf69 I'm also not sure about `quine`... About the trimming, my intention on the trimming and percentage format was to add a little bit of "work" that the program should do and make the frequencies a bit more different/challenging. Do you think I should drop the trimming part from the challenge?

Comment: I do think so, yes (also it might be better received that way)

Comment: I do not think the average person who does not use this site will know what a SBCS is, so it is probably still worth explaining. Alternatively, I think it would be cleaner to just require that the input be a byte and the output reflects the frequency of that byte. That way you don't eliminate multibyte languages from using it to their benefit, and I don't think it allows any "cheating."

Comment: Sounds okay to me. I agree that it is better to avoid elimination of multi-byte languages.

Comment: The thing I try to avoid is to get a lot of 0 bytes answers (for languages that print 0 as default). So I want to add a task that the program should do, like printing in percentage format. So the question is, before I reduced the trimming task, if this is enough to achieve that.

Comment: [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/209319/source-code-byte-frequency) with some changes listed in this edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Identify the tonic from a key signature

### Objective

Given a [key signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature) in major, output its tonic.

### Input

An integer from -14 to +14, inclusive. Its absolute value is the numbers of flats/sharps. Negative number represents flats, and positive number represents sharps. Note that [theoretical keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_key) are also considered.

### Mapping

Note the use of Unicode characters ♭(U+266D; music flat sign), ♯(U+266F; music sharp sign), (U+1D12A; musical symbol double sharp), and (U+1D12B; musical symbol double flat).

> -14 → C
> -13 → G
> -12 → D
> -11 → A
> -10 → E
> -9 → B
> -8 → F♭
> -7 → C♭
> -6 → G♭
> -5 → D♭
> -4 → A♭
> -3 → E♭
> -2 → B♭
> -1 → F
> 0 → C
> 1 → G
> 2 → D
> 3 → A
> 4 → E
> 5 → B
> 6 → F♯
> 7 → C♯
> 8 → G♯
> 9 → D♯
> 10 → A♯
> 11 → E♯
> 12 → B♯
> 13 → F
> 14 → C

Output must be a string. Whitespaces are permitted everywhere.

### Rule

- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

Comment: "Or a sequence of bytes representing a string in some existing encoding"? (I think this should be the default, but I don't remember seeing any meta post about it)

Answer (score 2):

## Simulate simple Bloons Tower Defense!

For those who are unaware of this legendary series of video games, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloons_Tower_Defense) is a link.

### The task

You are going to be given an integer number and type of bloon wave and two integers describing the damage and pierce (max amount of bloons you can damage in one attack) of each attack. Your task is to output in how many attacks can you destroy the bloon wave.

### Bloon types

For simplicity, there will be no special properties like `fortified`, `regrow`, `camo` e.t.c. White bloons will also not be present as, without special properties, they are the same as black bloons

```
Name - health - what it pops into
BAD   - 20000 - 3x DDT and 2x ZOMG
ZOMG - 4000  - 4x BFB
BFB   - 700   - 4x MOAB
MOAB - 200   - 4x Ceramic
DDT   - 350   - 6x Ceramic
Ceramic - 60    - 1x Rainbow
Rainbow - 1     - 2x Zebra
Zebra   - 1     - 2x Black
Black   - 1     - 2x Pink
Pink    - 1     - 1x Yellow
Yellow  - 1     - 1x Green
Green   - 1     - 1x Blue
Blue    - 1     - 1x Red
Red     - 1     - Nothing!
```

### I/O

Input: A string describing the type of bloon, and three integers: the amount of bloons in the wave, attack damage and attack pierce

Output: An integer describing how many attacks are needed for destroying the whole wave.

### Examples

Note: If there is not enough pierce `n` to attack the whole wave, then only the first `n` bloons are attacked

```
Input: Rainbow 3 2 10
Starting: 3x Rainbow
Attack 1: 12x Black
2: 20x Yellow 2x Black
3: 10x Blue 10x Yellow 2x Black
4: 10x Yellow 2x Black
5: 10x Blue 2x Black
6: 2x Black
7: 4x Yellow
8: 4x Blue
9: Done!
Output: 9
```

This is the 4/0/x Sniper Monkey:

```
Input: BFB 1 30 1
1: BFB(670)
2: BFB(640)
...
13: BFB(10)
14: 4x MOAB(180)
15: 1x MOAB(150) 3x MOAB(180)
...
19: 1x MOAB(30) 3x MOAB(180)
20: 4x Ceramic(60) 3x MOAB(180)
21: 1x Ceramic(30) 3x Ceramic(60) 3x MOAB(180)
22: 3x Ceramic(60) 3x MOAB(180)
...
27: 1x Ceramic(30) 3x MOAB(180)
28: 3x MOAB(180)
...
69: 1x Ceramic(30)
70: Done!
```

This is codegolf, so lowest byte-count wins

Comment: This is extremely complicated. I feel like this will be in unanswered for a while.

Comment: In the second example, how is ceramic destroyed without giving out any lower class bloons?

Comment: +1 because btd is awesome lol. However this is a very complicated challenge, even for people who know how the mechanics work. It might be better if you limit the problem to 1 pierce only

Comment: or you could even do a challenge that simply requires calculating the RBE for a bloon wave, that could still be an interesting challenge

Comment: actually RBE calculating is probably a bit too simple

Answer (score 2):

## Solve the Halting Problem for Oneplis

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem)

Oneplis is a "very simple esolang" (I don't want to count this one toward my esolangs) made by me which only have three commands. As you can probably see from the name, it is a subset of 1+, along the lines of Befinge.

The three commands are:

- `1`, which pushes 1. (Obviously!)
- `+`, which pops the top two numbers and pushes their sum. (Obviously!)
- `#`, pops a number *n* and jumps to the instruction after the *n*th (0-based) `#`.

Oneplis is almost certainly a (very limited) push-down automaton, since it's impossible to decrement a number and impossible to retrieve elements arbitrary deep in the stack! Oh, and the only way to read a number is with `#`, which cannot handle arbitrarily large numbers!

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins! Your output should be truthy for halting, and falsy for non-halting. You can use any set of five characters for the instructions. Don't care if it jumps to a non-existence `#` or trying to execute `+` when there are <2 numbers on the stack.

### Test cases

```
11+ -> True
1##1# -> False
1## -> True
11+1+###11+# -> True
11+##1#1 -> False
```

## Sandbox

- Test cases?
- Shall I require the answers to deal with errors?

Comment: For "nth `#`", is it 1- or 0-based? (I guess it's 0-based, but you need to be explicit on it anyway.)

Comment: @Bubbler Uh, ok. It's 0-based in 1+, but 0-based indexing does not make any sense in this challenge anyway, it's impossible to push 0... Should I change it to 1-based?

Comment: I don't think it's that nonsense, as the only effect is that all instructions between first and second `#`s are unreachable.

Comment: @Bubbler Oh, okay then. So if no one objects I'll post this to main.

Comment: if you don't plan to require answers to deal with errors then also mention that they don't need to worry about popping from an empty stack

Comment: Or: errors terminate the program.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's also good. Although, I prefer it this way.

Answer (score 2):

## Noncommutative Quineoid Triple

This is the hard mode of [Quineoid Triple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209753/45613)

Write three different programs such that ***all*** of the following properties hold:

- \$ A(B) = C \$
- \$ B(C) = A \$
- \$ C(A) = B \$
- \$ A(C) = -B \$
- \$ B(A) = -C \$
- \$ C(B) = -A \$
- \$ A(A) = \epsilon \$
- \$ B(B) = \epsilon \$
- \$ C(C) = \epsilon \$

Where:

- \$ f(g) \$ is the output obtained from feeding the program text of \$g\$ into program \$f\$
- \$ -x \$ is the program text of \$x\$ in reverse (reversed in terms of either raw bytes or unicode codepoints)
- \$ \epsilon \$ is the empty string / an empty output

## Rules and Scoring

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program length total, in bytes wins.
- Standard quine rules apply.
- Each program can be in any language. Any number of them may share languages or each may use a different language.
- Use any convenient IO format as long as each program uses a consistent convention.

  - Functions are allowed, as this counts as "any convenient IO".
- The result of feeding anything other than program text of one of the three programs is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

*Sandbox note: This is partially inspired by [There's a fault in my vault!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210638/48931), which I thought had some interesting ideas in it. This is my effort to frame those ideas in a clearer fashion.*

---

## Cops/Robbers: Create a weak block cipher

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)

In cryptography, we often use **block ciphers**, which are a form of keyed encryption. More specifically, for a plain text string \$s\$ and a secret key \$k\$, we design an **encryption function** \$E(s, k)\$ and a **decryption function** \$D(\hat{s}, k)\$ such that if we encrypt and then decrypt the text with the same key, we get back our original text. That is, we have \$D(E(s,k),k) = s\$ for all possible strings \$s\$ and \$k\$.

One security property a good block cipher has is that it is resistant against **key-recovery attacks**. This means that if we have the ability to run \$E(s, k)\$ and \$D(\hat{s}, k)\$ for various choices of \$s\$ and \$\hat{s}\$ and collect pairs of encrypted and decrypted text we cannot tell what the key is.

In this challenge, you will design a simple block cipher that is *intentionally vulnerable* to a key recovery attack, and challenge others to try and exploit it.

### The Cops' Challenge

1. **Design a block cipher.** Design an encryption function \$E(s,K)\$ and decryption function \$D(\hat{s},k)\$ that take strings (or your language's closest equivalent) of a fixed length \$16\$ bytes and a key of fixed length \$16\$ bytes and outputs a string of length \$16\$ bytes. Your \$E\$ and \$D\$ functions **must** have the property that \$D(E(s,k),k) = s\$ for **all** 16-byte strings \$s\$ and \$k\$.<sup>1</sup> The functions must be deterministic (not use any randomness) and pure (not rely on any outside state). Your \$E\$ and \$D\$ must work within the integer/float precision of your language. Specifically, you may not treat floating point as if it's arbitrary precision, nor may you assume integers of arbitrary size if your language utilizes fixed-size integers.
2. **Implement a secret key-recovery attack on your block cipher.** Write a program that makes calls to \$E\$ and \$D\$ for a secret, unknown key \$k\$ and fully recovers the key by observing properties of the input/output pairs. The key must be recovered with probability \$1\$ - you may not rely on probabilistic approaches.<sup>2</sup> You **must** treat \$E\$ and \$D\$ as black boxes, from which you can only observe their input and output. This means you must **not** utilize runtime introspection, timing information, or other side effects of the implementation. You **must** only pass full \$16\$ byte strings to \$E\$ and \$D\$, and not any other type. This means you may not rely on special objects with overloaded operators or similar to glean information about how the input is processed by \$E\$ and \$D\$. Your attack **may** be adaptive, in that it decides which strings to pass in based on outputs to previous strings. To enforce a practicality limit, your attack **must** work for a combined total of strictly less than \$2^{16}\ = 65536\$ calls to \$E\$ and \$D\$ for any key \$k\$. If the block cipher you design has the property that for keys \$k_1\$ and \$k_2\$ that \$E(s,k_1)=E(s,k_2)\$ and \$D(s,k_1)=D(s,k_2)\$ for all \$s\$, then we call these keys *functionally identical*, and your attack may recover any functionally identical key to the original.

That's it! You will reveal both the encryption and decryption functions \$E\$ and \$D\$, and challenge the robbers to find your key recovery attack (or possibly a different one).

Clearly, the challenge is to design your \$E\$ and \$D\$ to look secure, but they have some catastrophic weakness that allow you to recover the key with very few calls. Another approach is to 'trapdoor' the function in some way only known to you. In the spirit of [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), you are encouraged to post a short explanation of what your \$E\$ and \$D\$ do, especially if they are written in an esoteric language.

You may use cryptographic functions if you wish, but using them presents several practical problems. Hashing functions are designed to be one way and your are unlikely to be able to design both an encryption and decryption function that utilizes them. Symmetric ciphers have both encryption and decryption, but is unlikely to allow the key recovery attack outlined here.

If no-one mounts a successful attack in 7 days, you may post your key recovery attack and mark your answer as *safe*, which prevents it from being cracked. Note your submission can still be cracked until your reveal your attack.

Your answer is *invalid* if you do not follow the rules set above. Your answer can be declared invalid even after it is marked safe, if it turns out your revealed attack does not obey the rules.

The shortest safe submission, calculated as the sum of the bytes of the two functions \$E\$ and \$D\$, wins. Your functions must be named.

### The Robbers' Challenge

1. **Find a vulnerable answer.** That is an answer, which hasn't been cracked yet and which isn't safe.
2. **Crack it by designing a key recovery attack.** Your attack must follow the rules outlined in the cops section. To recap, this means:

   - The total number of calls to \$E\$ and \$D\$ with the key \$k\$ must be strictly less than \$2^{16}\$
   - You must only pass \$16\$ byte strings to \$E\$ and \$D\$, and must have the key \$k\$ initially be unknown
   - The attack may be adaptive but must work to recover any 16 byte key \$k\$ (or a functionally identical key)
   - You must treat \$E\$ and \$D\$ as black box, and may not use runtime introspection, timing information, etc.

If you've found such a attack, post an attack on the robber's thread linking back to the answer. If possible, you should post a link to an online interpreter which allows others to run your attack for various keys \$k\$. You are encouraged to post how your answer works, and the maximum number of calls your approach makes to \$E\$ and \$D\$. If your attack does not recover the key, but instead a functionally identical one, explain (briefly) why they are functionally identical.

You must not crack your own answer.

The user who cracked the largest number of answers wins the robbers' challenge. Ties are broken by the sum of bytes of cracked answers (more is better).

### Example #1

#### Python 3, 133 bytes (cop)

```python
E=lambda s,k:''.join(chr((ord(c)+ord(d))%256) for c,d in zip(s,k))
D=lambda s,k:''.join(chr((ord(c)-ord(d))%256) for c,d in zip(s,k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39U2JzE3KSVRoVgn20pdXS8rPzNPIzmjSEMjvyhFI1lTG0SlaGqqGpmaaSqk5RcpJOukKGTmKVRlFmgA9WhqcrkQMEKXoBH//wMA)

My program computes the sum of \$s_i\$ and \$k_i\$ for each \$i\$.

#### Python 3, cracks xxx's answer

```python
leaked_key = E('\0'*16,k)
print('key = %s' % leaked_key)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYyxDoIwFEV3vuIt5L0qGgFBY8Imf2FiSlukFltSWPDnK8bBkekO95wzzFPnbB7qquevRnIYE3NB3D@dtiQ6T@S8JMG235GMxVlRMmidB5FI0BbeeqDFYSy6riR26wlTIW@ELMrTWar2kWb5EUOvuFHybtQMFdSEtwNu0nLho8FrOxH@nnhEiOEPsxA@)

My crack completes in \$1\$ call and uses that fact that \$0 + k = k\$.

### Example #2

#### Python 3, 147 bytes (cop)

```python
def E(s,k):
 o=''
 V=[*range(256)]
 j=0
 for i in range(16):
  j+=V[i]+ord(k[0])
  j%=256
  V[i],V[j]=V[j],V[i]
  o+=chr(ord(s[i])^j)
 return o
D=E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@7DoMwDEX3fIWXKklh4NHSqpI3@AUWoBLlUQJSggKV0q9PE3XpUMm27HN1Bq/vfVIytbYfRijYFi78RkAhpQRKrI66lc@BJeeMNwRmjAiMSoMAIeEbxZkXYA6wrEQTKN2zpYoa7tkBnegWn4RlNTfoR@hPR1WA3aSZNzZH@H12kh72l5agSI6FXZDWJk5qk55qc85qc7m2j67/xyhZtZA7y1nBqAe/Td1Xrrj9AA)

My program uses a complicated thing.

#### Python 3, cracks yyy's answer

```python
leaked_key = ''
for c in range(256):
 if E('f'*16,chr(c))==E('f'*16,k):
  leaked_key = chr(c)+'x'*15
  break

print('key = %s' % leaked_key)
assert E('abcdabcdabcdabcd', leaked_key) == E('abcdabcdabcdabcd', k)
assert D('abcdabcdabcdabcd', leaked_key) == D('abcdabcdabcdabcd', k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU@7boMwFN39FTcDsh08JK3CUOlu5BdYEK0ImMS4wZFNpOTrqW@pUjpE6uDXed3jy308ueF1anUHexGUlW8MHHLOoMBy7evhqMXLLpMVgx43DDrnwYAZYKa2GRmgT7EoTZU63wpbbipJWILRGC/EqKLsK6RN0TOiLsXm5AU5QkTkex9NXo9XP4BjOe6ZRX686hDO@udYrfj0qWur2w@r74AQa1Kf5rcPVY2FDP2Gd3y9zRRNaaREfCDfn4Q/SbMo5bco2EXy4CPL2MWbYRR81iSBQ7KwSVaHoP1Io@pD0y4XV0shID4R2UdI/p@Q/EnINH0B)

They only ever use the first byte of the key, so we can just bruteforce the first byte and pad with anything to get a functionally identical key. This involves a maximum of \$256\$ calls to \$E\$ with the secret key.

---

<sup>1. This means that if your language uses null-terminated strings, such as C, then you should be using memcpy-type operations instead of string operations. Since the input length is fixed as 16 bytes, this should be no issue.
2. This requirement forbids most kinds of [Birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).</sup>

---

## Questions to sandbox users:

- I know this is a lot to take in. Is it clear?
- Can anyone think of a *trivial* way to trapdoor \$E\$ and \$D\$ with eg. a hashing function? I don't think it's possible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I love this idea! I think it's written in a pretty clear way, I _think_ you could trivially trapdoor _E_ and _D_, by doing something like `if (s == hash("sixteen_byte_str")) return k`, but disallowing cryptography functions should fix that

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Glad you think it's clear! Out of curiosity, if you wrote that as your encryption function, how would you write the corresponding decryption function?

Comment: Something like `if (ŝ == k) return hash("sixteen_byte_str")`, you'd just need to ensure there's no way it could be confused with a value that legitimately encrypts to `k` (which would be easily doable by replacing it with whatever `hash("sixteen_byte_str")` would typically encrypt to). Using crypto functions to trivially win a CnR challenge is practically a loophole, and is likely to be downvoted anyway. (Btw, when I write `x == hash("sixteen_byte_str")`, I mean `hash(x) == "sixteen_byte_str"`)

Comment: Actually, wait, I'm being stupid. I think there's no way to not have it return `hash(x) == "sixteen_byte_str"` in one of the two functions, so there doesn't appear to be a trivial way to trapdoor it. I'd still disallow crypto in case someone uses some sort of fancy asymmetric thing, but I can't figure it out if there is.

Answer (score 2):

## Take 6!

A good card game is a wonderful thing. I got me a nice fresh set of [Take 6!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_Nimmt!) Too bad though, I have no-one to play with. And so I turn to you!

### The Game

The game is played with a set of 104 cards, numbered 1 to 104 inclusively. Each card has a number of 'cows' attached. Here's a quick Python function to calculate the number of cows:

```python
def cows(card):
    out = 1
    if(card % 5) == 0:
        out += 1
    if(card % 10) == 0:
        out += 1
    if(card % 11) == 0:
        out += 4
        if(card % 5) == 0:  # C-c-c-combo
            out += 1
    return out
```

Therefore, there is a total of

- 1 card with 7 cows (number 55)
- 8 cards with 5 cows (the other multiples of 11: 11, 22, 33,
  44, 66, 77, 88, 99)
- 10 cards with 3 cows (multiples of ten: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,
  60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
- 9 cards with 2 cows (other multiples of five: 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 65, 75, 85, 95)
- 76 cards with 1 cow (all other cards)

The game is played by up to 10 players.

Each player is given 10 cards. 4 cards are placed on the table as the starts of 'rows'. Then 10 turns of play take place. Then, results are calculated.

#### A turn

Each player selects one of their remaining cards. At the same time, they reveal their selected cards.

Going in the order of lowest card number, the player whose card it is must place it into a row according to rules:

1. If there is a row with the top card of a lower number than the player's and no such row with a lower number exists, their card must be placed at the end of the row. If their card is the sixth in a row, they take the first 5 cards and put them on their result pile, leaving theirs as the new start.
2. If no such row exists, they must pick one of the rows, take all the cards there to their result pile, and leave their card as the new start.

Examples:

> row tops: 10 20 30 40
>
> played: 25
>
> must be placed on the row with a 20, creating the configuration 10 25 30 40 with a possible cow gain

> row tops: 10 20 30 40
>
> played: 9
>
> pick any row, creating for example 10 20 9 40, but guaranteed to gain cows

#### Counting

The sum of cow values of the cards in a player's result pile is their score. The lower the score the better.

Scores may be added up over several games, creating an overall score for a match.

### Bots

Bots will be standalone programs. Everything belonging to a bot will be placed in a single directory, the name of the directory will be used as the name of the bot. A launch script named `launch` (may be the entire bot) must be provided. If necessary, a compilation script named `build` may be provided. Both scripts shall be placed directly in the bot's directory and should use shebangs to specify how they are to be run.

Bots shall not interfere with other bots, the controller, or the git repositories used.

The bots will have the option of storing extra information in files in their own directory. It will be wiped when a fresh series is being run (such as after adding a new bot).

An override input format may be provided. I intend to use [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) for this, I'll write up some details when working on the controller. The default format will have all messages newline-terminated.

Once launched, the bot will be first given their cards, as a list of card numbers, where the numbers may or may not be ordered.

The default format will be

```
cards 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

No response is expected.

For each round, the bot will be prompted with the current state of the grid, that is the number of cards in each row, the sum of cows in each row and the top number card in the row.

The default format will be

```
count 1 2 3 4

cows 5 6 7 8

top 11 20 22 35
```

The bot shall answer with the number of one of its remaining cards.

The list of all the cards used by all bots in the round will be given to each bot. Not that this includes the bot's own card. The order of bots in this message will be consistent within a game.

The default format will be

```
used 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

No response is expected.

If the placement rule 2. has to be invoked, the bot will receive a message containing the board state at the time when it needs to pick a row

The default format will be

```
pickrow

count 1 2 3 4

cows 5 6 7 8

top 11 20 22 35
```

The bot shall respond with the number of the row it wishes to take. The rows will be 0-indexed for this.

If the bot's move results in a gain of result cows, it will be informed of which cards and how many cows it has gained (note that the lower the number the better).

The default format will be

```
cardgain 1 2 3 4 5

cowgain 6
```

No response is expected.

At the end, all bots will be shown their score as well as all the scores of others, in the order consistent with the used cards message.

The default format will be

```
score 30

others 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

No response is expected.

If the bot makes an invalid move, it will be delivered a special message informing it of such. From that point the bot's current game is over. It gets 100 points of penalty.

The default format will be

```
invalid
```

A timely shutdown is expected.

The bot may of course try to save information to its private file at any time, including at the end.

After the final message, the bot shall terminate in a timely manner.

Scoring will be added up over many games, number depends on how fast the games end up running, but at least 100 sounds reasonable to me.

Bots will be placed in a separate github repository **TODO** for easy setup and reseting. Bots that need a compilation script but don't have one will be given one.

### Controler

Work has started at https://github.com/MrRedstoner/Take6KOTH

The controller will be designed to run in Java 1.8+, using the Process API to launch bots.

## Notes:

While the number of bots is too low, it will be padded to 10 by using multiples of primitive bots. The tournament style once 11+ submissions exist is for now playing all subsets of size 10.

I intend to write up at least a few primitive bots, to get the games going. Something like using cards in the order they were given, or randomly. These will also demonstrate the custom input functionality. Maybe even one that uses external input, to let me play for fun!

Limits for execution time, storage of data etc. are not given at this time. If bots start to behave excessively limits may be added.

> Sandbox notes:
>
> Any better idea for tournament?
>
> Should bots be given the names of their competitors as well? Currently leaning towards yes.

Planned tags: [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Comment: Even though most people can read python, you should still include a written description of how the cows are counted. As it is, your program counts twice for it being divisible by 5 in the case of 55, is that intentional?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman it is indeed intentional, it's a combo for a reason :D. The result also matches what wikipedia describes about the game. Should have some more to edit soon so I'll make the change then.

Comment: But when do you take 720?? /s

Answer (score 2):

## Output all of printable ASCII using all of printable ASCII

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213530)

Comment: "Irreducible" isn't really an observable requirement; I'd recommend looking into using [tag:pristine-programming] to make it an objective criterion.

Comment: What do you mean by "observable"? "irreducible" simply means you can't purely remove characters (not purely substrings) from the program and have it still work (not merely not error). That's pretty objective, is it not?

Comment: Actually, yes it seems you're right, I was probably thinking of some other common criteria that isn't valid. Otherwise challenge looks good, doesn't seem to be a duplicate. I would say this isn't kolmogorov complexity since it's not constant but it is restricted source albeit not in the common usage.

Comment: Can my program contain additional **non**-ASCII bytes?

Comment: @Adám yes, in the post it says "Your program, and its output, can contain any additional non-printable-ASCII bytes (bytes, not characters) if you like, such as newlines". "non-printable-ASCII" includes "non-ASCII"

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe clarify that you mean both non-[printable-ASCII] and [non-printable]-ASCII.

Comment: Perhaps subtract 95 from each score so that scores look more reasonable

Comment: @Lyxal my reasoning for not doing that was because I suspect most answers will be quite a lot longer in order to make sure they're irreducible, it would complicate things, and IMO it doesn't really matter if they're that length

Answer (score 2):

## [Count the Collatz survivors mod 2^n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213990/count-the-collatz-survivors-mod-2n) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Answer (score 2):

## Round a Matrix

Your input is a 2d array of nonnegative floats `A`. It can be supplied in whatever format is most acceptable for your language. It can have any dimensions.

Let `r` and `c` be the 1d arrays of row and column sums of `A` respectively, rounded to the nearest integer, with the rule that `0.5` is rounded up to `1`.

Your task is to output a 2d array of nonnegative integers `B` such that `|b_{ij} - a_{ij}| < 1` for all `i` and `j`, and also the row and column sums of `B` are equal to `r` and `c` respectively.

In other words, `B` is obtained by rounding each element of `A` up or down, in such a way that the row and column sums are preserved.

There may be many possible solutions. In this case, you only need to output one of them.

If there is no solution, your program's behaviour can be undefined.

Example:

```
 A = 1.2 3.4 2.4
     3.9 4.0 2.1
     7.9 1.6 0.6
```

in this case, the row sums are `[7.0, 10.0, 10.1]` and the column sums are `[13.0, 9.0, 5.1]` so after rounding these, you get `r = [7 10 10]` and `c = [13 9 5]`. One acceptable solution is

```
 B = 1   3   3
     4   4   2
     8   2   0
```

This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

### Motivation

I am also interested in what clever algorithms people can come up with. I guess the most obvious is just to do a random search, but that can take a very long time, even if the array is only 10x10 or so.

### Questions

- Is it clear? Please can you edit it if it's not in the right format?
- Has it appeared here before? (I don't think so, because I was searching Stackoverflow for a while in order to come up with a solution to this.)
- Is there always a solution under the conditions given here?
- Would it be better in some other format than code golf?
- Should the condition `|b_{ij} - a_{ij}| < 1` be `|b_{ij} - a_{ij}| <= 1`?

Comment: Since you want optimal, interesting solutions, rank by time complexity. You'll get fewer answers, but they will be more optimal than a direct brute force approach.

Comment: The suggestion of using complexity isn't often a good one - most challenges here that try to do that wind up closed or unanswered. It would be much simpler to go by execution time for some number of test cases that you pick. For the actual question, I think you should explicitly say that `r` and `c` are computed by summing and then rounding (assuming that is the correct order) as it isn't precisely clear from what you have right now.

Answer (score 2):

## [The Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence (posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/214423)

Comment: There are the square roots of [A127546](https://oeis.org/A127546). It looks like there are ways to generate this sequence shorter than just generating Fibonacci numbers and adding their squares. So, this doesn't strike me as a duplicate but an interesting challenge in its own right. I'd recommend removing the square-root step from the challenge and just asking for the sum of the three squares, which is a whole number. This might also allow for more interesting recursive solutions. You should include test cases, perhaps something like the first 15 elements of the sequence and maybe one big one.

Comment: For clarity, I also recommend explicitly giving the formula for the k-th term in terms of the respective Fibonacci numbers, so that solvers don't need to know the Pythagorean formula for the diagonal of a prism. And, just in case, give the recursive formula for the i'th Fibonacci numbers. Mathjax is enabled here, but you have to use `\$` delimiters in place of `$`.

Comment: @xnor Just throwing in an equation seems odd for a code golf challenge. Do you have any ideas for context? Or is that okay here? (I guess I could always just write that you have to square it after...)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here. I do think it would be good to keep the Fibonacci prism context as some motivation and flavor. I'm not suggesting removing that, but adding a formula like \$g(n)=F_n^2 + F_{n+1}^2 + F_{n+2}^2\$ (or with a square root if you want to keep that) and the definition of Fibonacci numbers \$F_n\$. I can say there's a preference here for challenges to have the task easy to read by skimming. And, to give a formula if possible and save solvers a bit of a time from doing math problem, although clever golfers may find shorter alternative ways to express or compute it.

Comment: I've edited the question. Is that what you wanted @xnor?

Comment: Yes, this looks good. You should still add test cases. I'd suggest also linking https://oeis.org/A127546.

Comment: I think the first test case ought to be `1 ==> 6`

Comment: @Giuseppe Yeah, you're right. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I made some clean-up edits, in part to avoid references to programs and functions, since either is allowed by allowed.

Comment: @xnor Thank you! When should I post this (out of the sandbox)? (I'm new :D)

Comment: @nthnchu The usual recommendation is 3 days minimum, but it's really up to you. I just read through it again, and I think it all looks good. One minor thing is that we allow [zero-indexing for sequence challenges by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17172/20260), which would allow doing the mapping as `0 ==> 6, 1 ==> 14, ...`. So I think it would be good to say that input may be taken zero-indexed to remind solvers of this.

Comment: @xnor I choose the 1 index off of \${F_1}^2+{F_{1+1}}^2+{F_{1+2}}^2 = 6\$. 0 would therefore be \${F_0}^2+{F_{0+1}}^2+{F_{0+2}}^2 = 2\$. The index is based off of \$F_0=0\$ and \$F_1=1\$

Answer (score 2):

## I only want some primes, not all of them

It is well known that there are various [formulae for calculating primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) that span from calculating a subset of primes, to all possible primes. However, for this challenge, I only want a specific subset.

You are to write a program which takes a single natural integer \$n>0\$ as input. This program will then output a [function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/66833), \$f(p)\$, which will take a integer \$p\ge0\$ and do the following:

- If \$p < n\$, return the \$p\$th value of a contiguous subset length \$n\$ of primes
- If \$p \ge n\$, returns a non-prime integer (including \$0\$, \$1\$ and negative integers).

For example, Euler's quadratic \$p^2+p+41\$ returns the \$p\$th value of the subset of primes \$\{41, 43, 47, ..., 1601\}\$ for \$0 \le p \le 39\$. However, for \$p=43\$, this returns \$1933\$, which is prime, so this would not be a valid function to return for \$n = 40\$.

You may choose the subset (and it may differ for different \$n\$), so long as it is finite and contiguous. You may also choose to use 1-indexing for \$p\$, meaning that \$f(p)\$ returns primes for \$1 \le p \le n\$.

You may output in the most natural form of a function in your language. For example, Jelly would return a string representing a link, Python would return a named function or lambda etc.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

## Meta

- Thoughts and feedback?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Tags are [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes), [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming). Any others?

Comment: 1. Why output a function and not just have a program with two inputs?

2. Maybe you should note that 0, 1, and negative numbers are not prime.

3. I also think you should clarify that "length n" refers to the subset, not its elements. That intially confused me for a while.
4. What if \$p\$ or \$n\$ is negative? Or zero? - is the "\$p\$th value" using a 0-based index?

Comment: @pxeger 1. the idea of the challenge is based on prime calculating formulae, so I want submissions to return "a formula" for a given \$n\$, rather than just a single value for two values \$n\$ and \$p\$. Whether the "formula" is a mathematical one or just "if \$p<n\$ then ... else ..." is irrelevant. 2, 3, 4. All clarified

Comment: "a natural integer \$p \ge 0\$" - zero isn't technically a natural number. Personally I think you should just drop the "natural" because an inequality is clearer.

Comment: @pxeger There's some disagreement about whether \$0\$ is natural or not (something I've had to deal with in past challenges), but I agree, the inequality + just "integer" is much clearer

Answer (score 2):

[Question has been posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214938/convert-magic-the-gathering-colours-to-a-colour-based-deck-name)

Comment: Seems to be a heavy dictionary-ing challenge that might not make it suitable, but otherwise cool idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Middle-Square RNG: What Number Came Before? (WIP)

A well-known, but statistically poor, way of generating random numbers is to square the number and take the middle digits (when expressed in base 10)

Your task is to take a 4-digit number as input and output any 4-digit number that produces the input number (there may be more than one, which is one of the statistical flaws of this method) when applying middle-square. If the square has an odd number of digits, take an extra digit off the left side.

If there is no such number (some numbers with this method have no predecessor- yet another statistical flaw), indicate that clearly in a way that cannot be mistaken as a valid answer. Some possible ways of indicating this:

- Output nothing
- Output null/None/nil/false
- Output an empty list
- Output a negative number
- Output an error message that is clearly not a 4-digit number
- Throw an exception
- Crash
- Exit with a nonzero status

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: Is there a theoretical guarantee that any number if attainable? (i.e. is there always a solution?)

Comment: @RobinRyder no. Some numbers have no predecessor.

Answer (score 2):

## Operational countdown

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

- Posted.

Comment: How to handle floating point imprecision in this given that your doing floating point division and roots then checking to see if those are integers?  I cooked up a solution in Perl that is off by 1 on several of your examples because as it gets near 1, the subtraction ends in `.999999.....`.

Comment: @Xcali it's a trivial part of the challenge, this kind of problem is common to many languages, anyway I think that Perl, like most of languages, can handle integer numbers properly.

Answer (score 2):

## A Snake, A Camel And A Kebab.

As many of you will know, almost every programming language has a standard casing system; unfortunately, we have not been able to agree on a singular system to use and now must frequently switch between camelCase, snake_case and kebab-case.

Now I know what you're thinking... wouldn't it be nice if we had a program that could convert from one casing to another?
Well - soon we're going to have plenty!!! *(This is where you come in)*

### Challenge

You're job is to write a program/function that will take an input string, and a casing system. It will then print/return the converted string.

#### Inputs:

You're program will receive two inputs, an alphabetic string that is to be converted and a string that **will always** be one of `kebab` `camel` or `snake`.

#### Outputs:

You're program should output a string that conforms to the new casing if it is possible. If the input string was invalid, and had mixed casing, you're program should print/do nothing.

### Test Cases:

Valid Examples:
`"aJavaVariable", "snake" = "a_java_variable"`
`"a_python_variable", "kebab" = "a-python-variable"`
`"golf", "camel" = "golf"`
`"", "snake" = ""`
`"doHTMLRequest", "kebab" = "do-h-t-m-l-request"`

Invalid Examples (*no output*):
`"an_InvalidName", "kebab"`
`"invalid-inPut_bad", "camel"`

### Additional Info:

- As most programming languages prefer lowercase variable names, you should convert all letters to lowercase unless it is needed to be upper case for camel casing.

---

## Meta

- Is this a duplicate? I couldn't find any quite like it.
- Are the rules clear?
- Would it lead to more creative answers if I remove the possibility of being given invalid input, and assume all input will be valid?

Comment: I _think_ you should remove the invalid input handling, as it might only increase the code length..

Comment: Very very similar to [this,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70180/coding-convention-conversion), except there's an extra casing requirement.

Comment: @Razetime Good find. I think that although the premise of the question is very similar, the difference in triggering which case to convert to, will lead to very different code logic.

Comment: Suggested expansion: PascalCase

Answer (score 2):

## How Many Atoms?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

[Post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216723/how-many-atoms)

Comment: So we don't need to handle `(Ne(St(Ed_2)_3)_4)_5` formulas?

Comment: @Bubbler adding that in as a test case

Comment: Looks like your test cases have some typos.  `H_20` should have an answer of 20, or the `0` should be an `O`.  Also, the third to last has an `_` after a number (`C_21_H...`), which doesn't seem right. 

In general, though, if the goal here is just to count the atoms, and not to check the validity of a formula, I find that the BNF and the list of elements is unnecessary and confusing to the task at hand.  It seems like the challenge is going to be about validating a formula and then it becomes something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

## [Eye test - How many squares are in this picture?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216919/66833)

Answer (score 2):

## [Based Palindromes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216929/based-palindromes)

Comment: “All integer base 10 numbers below 1000” would include negative numbers. Based on your test cases, you should clarify that you mean non-negative or positive numbers. Also, wouldn’t 0 be a palindrome in any base? Why is it excluded from the base 2 test case?

Comment: @water_ghosts alright, i've edited the problem to show that it's only from 0-1000 inclusive, as well as added 0 to the output for base 2.

Comment: This title is a downgrade from "Based Palindromes"

Comment: @Razetime haha, i didn't know whether "based palindromes" made it clear what the challenge was and so i changed it. I've changed it back, though.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69707/all-your-base-palindromic-belong-to-us). This is a simpler challenge than most of the other challenges that ask for palindromes in multiple bases, so I think it's fine.

Comment: Now that this has been posted, I've edited it down to save space

Answer (score 2):

## Partial sums of the kempner series [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217090/partial-sums-of-the-kempner-series)

Comment: Can we output rational numbers (or numerator/denominator pairs) instead of floats?

Comment: @Dingus , yes according to the [Default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19024). Do you think I should specify this in the challenge?

Answer (score 2):

## Run the lottery

#### Rules

Your job is to write a program to accept lottery tickets, adding all the money to a pool, and divvy out the winnings based on how many numbers each ticket has guessed correctly. The amount of money people spent on their tickets is used to determine how much each person should take home.

1. You will receive a list of lottery tickets, which will be how much the person has paid, along with 5 numbers between 1 and 25. The numbers do not have to be unique, and order matters. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [3, 2, 1, 4, 5] are considered different, and [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] is a valid ticket.
2. You will also receive 5 numbers between 1 and 25, which are the winning numbers. This follows the same restrictions as a participant's ticket.
3. Each participant will be given a "score" based on how many numbers they guessed correctly. They must guess the number, and guess it in the correct spot as well. [x, x, 1, x, x] is not a winning number for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. [1, 1, 1, 2, 3] counts as 2 correct guesses for [1, 2, 1, 1, 1].
4. The score is \$4^n\$  where \$n\$ is the number of winning numbers. Yes, a participant with 0 correct numbers has a score of 1, and is eligible to take home *some* money.
5. Each participant's final weight is their score times the amount they spent on the ticket. A person with a score of 4 (1 correct guess) and paid $4 for a ticket has the same weight as a person with a score of 16 (2 correct guesses) and paid $1 for their ticket.
6. Finally, the prize pool is then divvied up. 10% goes to you, the lottery company. The remaining 90% gets divvied up proportionally by each participant's final weight, rounded to the cent.

The input and output of the program can be in any format. The only stipulation is that monetary values must be decimals. For instance, $15.68 cannot be represented as 1568.

#### Example game

The winning numbers are as follows

- [2, 18, 1, 15, 7]

Four people bought tickets with the following prices and numbers

- $6, [9, 5, 6, **15**, 22], one match, score of 4, weight of 24
- $2, [**2**, 25, 17, 7, **7**], two matches, score of 16, weight of 32. Notice how only the second 7 counts, order matters
- $67, [11, 16, 9, 20, 16], no matches, score of 1, weight of 67
- $1, [12, 19, 6, 25, 2], no matches because the 2 is in the wrong spot, score of 1, weight of 1

The total pool is $76, $68.4 after we take our cut, which is then sent out based on the weights. The sum of all weights is 124.

- First ticket gets 24/124, $13.24
- Second ticket gets 32/124, $17.65
- Third ticket gets 67/124, $36.96
- Fourth ticket gets 1/124, a whole 55 cents

Comment: I think you should explain that the winning numbers are not necessarily distinct in rule 2, instead of leaving it until the examples. Likewise, you should state the 'order matters' rule earlier.

Comment: @Dingus I added those clarifications to rules 1-3. Thoughts?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Is each bracket matched?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string)

Given a string consisting only of the characters `()[]{}`, determine if each type of bracket is matched--that is, every `(` corresponds to one later `)`, every `[` corresponds to one later `]`, and every `{` corresponds to one later `}` (and vice-versa).

Pairs *are* allowed to overlap: `([)]` is just as valid as `([])`.

Output one consistent value for one classification and anything else for the other, or following your language's truthiness semantics (inverted if you want).

### Test cases:

Matched:

```
()
[]
{}
()[]{}
()()([])
{[][}]
{{{}}}
([{}]){([]})
[(()())(((())))(]()(()))
```

Not matched:

```
(
]
{{}
[)
(()())((((()))))(()()(())(())))
{}{}{)
[())[])]
)(
```

### Meta

- Does this admit a variety of interesting solutions?
- Would it be better to add `<>` as a bracket type? Have fewer bracket types? Arbitrarily many?
- I'm writing this up entirely because I'm surprised it hasn't been asked yet, so although I have looked, this might still be a duplicate.
- Although I don't think it's necessarily *unclear*, I feel like the specification could be worded better.

Comment: [very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77138/78850)

Comment: @Lyxal indeed lol

Answer (score 2):

## Count strictly overlapping substrings [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) [subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218978)

Comment: Is it correct that `1` is never a valid result?

Comment: @Adám yes; do you think I should add that?

Comment: Probably a good idea.

Comment: You need test cases with longer `b`s that can overlap themselves in multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

## Pad a jagged array to be square [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219041)

Comment: Add a test case for pad value -1 or something like that.

Comment: Can any dimension of the input array be 0? [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: Also add a test case with an array consisting of only fill values.

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean by "[please review other sandbox posts]"? I don't see the need for a test case with pad value -1, because the type of the elements in the array is answer-defined. I'll clarify the other two though

Comment: I suggest that you specify more clearly what input formats are allowed, that is, what counts as an "array". For example, is it acceptable to take lines of text with space as separator within each line? Or use two types of brackets, such as `{[1, 5, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 5]}`?

Comment: @LuisMendo input should be taken in your language's natural representation of nested arrays. If it doesn't have a builtin array representation, then take it in some kind of text representation like I mentioned in the rules section

Comment: The problem with saying "natural representation" is that a language may have more than one way of representing nested tuples. That said, I think what you have in the question is alright - perhaps to clarify what Luis is talking about you could add: "input can be any unambiguous representation of a jagged array"? I think what Luis may be getting at is that there could be a problem with e.g. a Python array contains meta-information (the length) while a C array wouldn't, but usually I think that is left out.

Comment: To explain my point better: MATLAB (or MATL) can use curly braces for arbitrary arrays, and square brackets for rectangular arrays. So either `{{1, 5, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 2, 5}}` or `{[1, 5, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 5]}` could be used as input. The latter is probably better to reduce code length. Can we just choose the most convenient one? What is the limit where choosing a convenient format counts as "pre-processing" the input and is not allowed? All this is language-dependent, but some general specification would be needed

Comment: @pxeger Something that I tend to add to my sandbox review comments recently, hoping to reduce the problem of the sandbox posts not being reviewed enough.

Comment: @LuisMendo You can probably choose any convenient one (I think that's the common consensus?)

Comment: The "-1" thing is just to make people notice that the value to be padded is an input rather than hard coded by the code.

Answer (score 2):

### <strike>Snail word</strike>

Very similar to other challenges

Comment: [tag:code-golf] [tag:ASCII-art]

Comment: Otherwise looks clear enough.  [*please review other sandbox posts*] While trying to search for duplicates https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bascii-art%5D+spiral+%5Bcode-golf%5D+is%3Aq  gives https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103064/roll-cake-phrases?noredirect=1&lq=1 which adds a middle layer , and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75446/draw-spiral-words which (appears to) allow overlapping (although it's quite unclear in that part) -- so I don't think there's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Consider adding a test case for length-1 input and "the input will never be empty".

Answer (score 2):

## Integer partitions into fixed parts with coprime constraint, and exclusion set

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[integer-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions)[recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion)

## Background

Let \$a\$ \$\in \mathbb{N}\$, \$b\$ \$\in \mathbb{N}\$, \$c\$ \$\in \mathbb{N}\$ and \$S\$ be some subset of \$\{i:1\leq i\leq a\}\$.

Consider \$X(a ,b, c, S)\$: The number of integer partitions of \$a\$ into \$b\$ many parts, where each of the parts are co-prime to \$c\$ and no part is contained within \$S\$.

Formally, for \$b=2\$

$$X(a ,2, c, S) = |\{(x, y): x + y = a,\ gcd(c, x) = gcd(c, y) = 1, x \notin S, y \notin S,\ x \leq\ y\}|$$

## Challenge

Codegolf, standard rules apply. Write code to calculate the function \$X(a ,b, c, S)\$ above.

Inputs:

- \$a\$, an integer. Your function **does not** need to be correct for \$a \le 2\$.
- \$b\$, an integer. Your function **does not** need to be correct for \$b \le 1\$.
- \$c\$, an integer.
- \$S\$, can be any set of integers between \$1\$ and \$a\$ (inclusive). The elements of \$S\$ are unique.

## Test-cases

Below test cases are written in the following format: \$a, b, c, S =\$ Answer

```
3, 2, 2, {} = 0
4, 2, 2, {} = 1
4, 2, 3, {2} = 0
7, 3, 5, {} = 3
7, 3, 2, {5} = 1
11, 3, 1, {} = 10
11, 3, 2, {} = 4
11, 3, 3, {5, 7} = 1
```

## BONUS

Brownie points for anyone who can do either of the following:

1. Disprove the following recursive relationship.
2. Extend the following recursive relationship (for higher values of \$b\$), and/or write code utilising it.

Recursive formula for \$b = 3\$ (Might be incorrect):

$$X(a ,3, c, S) = \sum_{i=1}^{i=\lfloor\frac{a}{2}\rfloor} {X(a - i, 2, c, T_i)} $$

With

$$T_0 = S$$

and,

$$T_i = T_{i-1}\cup\{i - 1, a + 1 - i\},\ for\ i \geq 1$$

## Questions for sandbox

Is this challenge good to go?

Comment: you can add tags here via `[tag:<tagname>]`.

Comment: @Razetime , sorry total noob here. In the comment section? or do I edit the post and add the [tag:<tagname>] at the end?

Comment: in the post. Add it near the title, like in the other posts.

Comment: About test cases. It looks like that this challenge doesn't have too many test cases, don't need a lot.

Comment: I think the info about integer types makes the question harder to read (they all have default rules), so I removed it.

Comment: The tag doesn't matter too much, as long as there's a code golf tag. // Usually people don't like time limits, but if you insist there's either "solutions must have time complexity that does not exceed  (something)" or "you must be able to run the program to completion with the following test cases" or "the program must finish on my machine in X seconds" (requires you running the programs) [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for the edits. Yes I suppose I'm not interested in any time constraints. Rather just interested to see the solutions people can come up with. Yes I will need to make some test cases, will add them when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

## Gray code... Gray code?

#### Your Task

Your task is to print (in an easily readable and consistent format) the binary representations of the numbers 0-255 in some order such that only one bit is altered between two consecutive numbers.

#### Your Restrictions

Each successive byte of the source code after the first can only change one bit from the previous byte.

#### Other Information

*Example valid code (in utf-8)*: `q1!#c`. Here, `q` (0**1**110001) and `1` (0**0**110001) are different in only one bit, and so on

*Example invalid codes (in utf-8)*: `Q1!`, `"!"`

*Example valid outputs (seperated by an empty line)*:

```
10101010 10101011 11101011 ... 01010101

[10, 11, 1011, 1111, 1110, ...]

10
0
1
11
111
...
```

*Example invalid outputs (seperated by an empty line)*:

```
0000000100000011000000100000000000000100...

0
01
10
11
100
...

0 1 ... 100000000 110000000 ... 11111111

00 01 11 10 0100 0101 ...

0 1 3 2 5 6 ...
```

*Notes*:

- A character can be stored as two bytes, but the bytes must differ by only one bit
- If your interpreter ignores a character (like Whitespace ignores almost all characters) it cannot be used

Comment: Is printing `1 3 2 6 7 5 4` and onwards ok?

Comment: What does "some form of gray code" mean exactly? / Clarify that the restriction part applies to the **source code** of the program.

Comment: I'll change it to binary gray code to avoid confusion.

Comment: You should describe what the gray code is to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Do you think this challenge is too hard?

Comment: Is it okay if the output is printed in decimal instead of binary?

Comment: Perhaps add "addition of leading zeroes doesn't count as a change" and some examples to illustrate/example valid output (just for challenge accessibility, this is implied from the definition (and the Wikipedia page))

Comment: Would be hard for practical languages, but for everything-are-valid languages it should not be a problem. Good challenge idea.

Comment: Does the last statement means "Your program should not work by removing any single bytes", or "Any subsequence of your program should not work."?

Comment: @tsh neither. It means that you can't use a character if it is completely skipped over by the interpreter. For example, in the python code
"if len('abc') < 4:
    print('Hello, World')"
the "c" can still be used because it is not skipped over by the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## Draw four colorful quarter circles

The challenge is to reproduce this image in your favorite language:

[image]

- Your image must be at least 400 by 400 pixels.
- The fill colors don't need to be the same as in the image but they must be different from each other.
- You must include the outlines but they can be any visible thickness you choose.
- The quarters should be at the same orientation as in the image.
- Your image must have four quarter circles aligned as in the image which each touch the edge of the circle at a point.
- Your code must take input which specifies the location, in pixels, of the point where the quarter-circles meet; you can take this input in any reasonable format, but the units must be pixels (no relative units, such as a fraction of the width/height of the image). You can assume these inputs are always within the bounds of the outer circle.  You can also assume that the inputs are such that all four quarter circles can be drawn within the circle.

Here is some LaTeX code as an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

  \coordinate (point) at (-0.1,0.4);

  \draw [name path=mycirc] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
  \path [name path=di-1] (point) -- ++(-2,2);
  \path [name path=di-2] (point) -- ++(-2,-2);
  \path [name path=di-3] (point) -- ++(2,-2);
  \path [name path=di-4] (point) -- ++(2,2);
  
  \foreach \col [count=\i] in {yellow,red,blue,brown}{
  
      \fill [red, name intersections={of=mycirc and di-\i}] (intersection-1) circle [radius=0.05] node (inter-\i) {};
      
      \fill[\col,draw=black,rotate around={(\i+3)*90:(point)}] (point)
        let \p1 = ($(point) - (inter-\i)$) in 
        arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius={0.707*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]
        -- +(270:{0.707*veclen(\x1,\y1)}) -- cycle ; 
  }
  
  \fill[red] (point) circle [radius=0.05];
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[I would love help on how to improve this challenge.]

Comment: Describing the exact ratios of the shapes would be helpful in drawing them

Comment: Those are quarter-circles, not semicircles

Comment: Might be more interesting if the center of the shape (where the petals meet) was an input

Comment: @pxeger ahem.. thanks :)

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman Could you say exactly how that could be specified?

Comment: @Anush Since the image is 300 x 300 pixels, you could say something like `you must take input which specifies the location, in pixels, of the point where the quarter-circles meet; you can take this input in any reasonable format, but the units must be pixels (no relative units, such as a fraction of the width/height of the image). You can assume these inputs are always within the bounds of the outer circle.`

Comment: "Your image must be at least 400 by 400 pixels" what about vector graphics? If some one choice to output the image with vector graphics format. How to define its width and height?

Answer (score 2):

## [Reconstruct an integer from its prime exponents](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220260/reconstruct-an-integer-from-its-prime-exponents)

Answer (score 2):

## [Subarrays With At Least N Distinct Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220422/subarrays-with-at-least-n-distinct-integers)

Comment: I don't get it. From `1,2,2,3` you can make 3 subsequences of `2` integers: 12; 22; 23. And the middle one is not made of different integers. So how it comes that "the number of contiguous subsequences that contain at least N distinct integers" is 5 in this case?

Comment: @Sheik `1,2`, `1,2,2`, `2,2,3`, `2,3`, `1,2,2,3` are the subsequences that contain at least 2 distinct integers. In my opinion, there should be a column in the table of test-cases that contains these sub-sequences for clarity.

Comment: @Hyperbole thank you very much. It wasn't that hard to get but, I don't know, English is not my language. Anyway if not on the test cases, they should be at least in an example before the tests.

Comment: @Hyperbole I appreciate the feedback. I updated the post with the example.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti I have updated the post with the example.

Answer (score 2):

## Tri tri tribonacci

Tribonacci from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers):

> The tribonacci numbers are like the Fibonacci numbers, but instead of starting with two predetermined terms, the sequence starts with three predetermined terms and each term afterwards is the sum of the preceding three terms.

### The challenge

Given three arrays of three integers, for each array:

1. Find the generator G (the first non-negative integer) of the sequence to which the three numbers belong
2. Then find the G-th element of the sequence (**zero-indexed***)

The three integers found are indeed part of a tribonacci sequence, output the G-th element of that sequence.

<sub>*The sequences are zero-indexed because G may be 0 and in that case you have to find the 0th element of the sequence.</sub>

### Example

Given the input

```
[[5, 11, 20], [1, 2, 3], [23, 39, 67]]
```

`5 11 20` are part of the sequnce `2 4 5 11 20`, which starts with `2`, so we take the 2nd element of the sequence: `5`

`1 2 3` are part of `0 1 0 1 2 3`, so we take `0`

`23 39 67` are part of the sequence `7 11 5 23 39 67 129 235` so we take `235`

Now `5 0 235` are part of the sequence `230 5 0 235` so the output is the 230th element of that sequence:

```
174892031986606286607812889236621806383715371411020300455075910
```

### Input / output

You can take the input as you prefer: an array of three arrays, three arrays, an object, a string, etc.

You are not required to handle integers larger than those implemented by your chosen language, I will post plenty of test cases with smaller output after I make a program for the challenge.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), everyone wins.

## Meta

Please say something.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to put `This is [tag:code-golf], everyone wins.`? That's not code golf :p

Comment: Looks fine to me, except for the "zero-indexed" part. 0-indexing and 1-indexing are usually equally allowed. (Also, people might complain about "why not just make it two challenges, one for finding the generator and one for n-th tribonacci")

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms we keep the truth in the sandbox, I will put *"the shortest wins"* in the challenge

Comment: @Bubbler the zero-indexing is because the sequence may start with 0, and in that case you have to find the 0th element of the sequence. About splitting the challenge, I didn't check but it's possible that one or both of the parts already exist.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti That makes sense. Then it would be better to include the justification of why it should be 0-indexed in the post.

Comment: @Bubbler I added a note to justify the restriction, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Maybe "This is code golf, so shortest code wins, but who's counting?" instead of "everyone wins"?

Answer (score 2):

## [Decompress an integer, Jelly style](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221428/decompress-an-integer-jelly-style)

Comment: Algorithm description looks good. Requiring to handle inputs up to \$2^{64}-1\$ sounds unfair to the languages that do not support that large integers though. I'd prefer something in the line of [the 5th bullet under the Rules on this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210071/78410).

Answer (score 2):

## [Leave a wake of dead cells behind you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224147/leave-a-wake-of-dead-cells-behind-you)

Comment: What if this is impossible?

Comment: @Beefster Then I'll happily accept a proof of impossibility

Answer (score 2):

## [Sr. 4Der says make this shape! (Episode 1)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222775/sr-4der-says-make-this-shape-episode-1)

Comment: I feel like it might be better if the answerers just chose the character they wanted to use, and then this would be a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge.

Comment: "Adjust the size if needed" isn't a very precise requirement. What's the smallest valid solution? What are the necessary and sufficient requirements for a solution to be valid?

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 2):

[(Σ*)² ⟲ Σ* (aka Round-Trip a String Pair)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222560/%ce%a3%c2%b2-%e2%9f%b2-%ce%a3-aka-round-trip-a-string-pair)

Answer (score 2):

## [Check B-powersmoothness - posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222652/check-b-powersmoothness)

Comment: Can you link to the wiki article please.

Comment: @Alexbries I added a link

Answer (score 2):

## Unique languages

As we [found out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222632/whats-my-tio-uniqueness) before, each of the 680 languages on Try it online! has a "TIO uniqueness", defined as the length of the shortest substring that appeared in the language's name and no others'.

This time, we're going to make it more general. Given a list of strings `S` and a target `T`, output the length of the shortest substring of `T` that is not in any other element of `S`.  You may choose whether `T` is part of `S` or not. The elements of `S` will always be unique. All elements of `S`, and `T`, will only contain lowercase letters (`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`). You may also take input as uppercase if you wish.

Your score will be calculated as `code length × TIO uniqueness`, where `code length` is measured in bytes and `TIO uniqueness` is the TIO uniqueness as specified [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222632/66833). If a language has an undefined TIO uniqueness, it cannot compete in this challenge.

The answer with the lowest score wins.

## Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- Thoughts on the scoring?
- Tags are [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), [subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence). Suggestions?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: Closely related: [Shortest Uniquely Identifying Substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166038/shortest-uniquely-identifying-substrings). No particular thoughts on the scoring.

Answer (score 2):

## [Quoted rational numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222882/quoted-rational-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

## Battery charging tracker

*If there are any better titles please post them in the comments*

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) *If any more tags might be appropriate, please post them in the comments*

---

The task here is to create a program which can output a battery's percentage at all times. It will be given input in the form of an array of "indications". These dictate when to plug and unplug the charger.

If this sounds confusing, let us take this sample input:

```
[[12, 23, 34], [15, 28, 67]]
```

*Note: you can take input in the form of a list of strings or a single string if you would like.*

The first array indicates the number of seconds to wait before unplugging the charger, and the second one indicates the number of seconds to wait before plugging in the charger. There will never be two coinciding values in one of the arrays or between the arrays. So `[[11, 22, 33], [15, 22, 34]]` is not valid input and neither is `[[1, 2, 3, 3, 6], [15]]`. Both arrays are guaranteed to have at least one value in them. Also, all values are positive non-zero integers.

The "battery" we are trying to simulate starts with 0%. When your program runs, the charger is automatically "plugged in", and each second the charge should tick up by 1% if the charger is plugged in, and decrease by 1% if it is not.

Each second, the program should output the amount of charge the battery has. It should not charge beyond 100% and should not go down below 0%; if the battery hits 100% then it will stay there until the charger is unplugged and if it hits 0% it will stay there until the charger is plugged in.

In addition, your program should store a "second counter" containing information on how long the program has been running for. When this counter hits any of the integers in either of the input arrays, the charger will be either unplugged or plugged in depending on which array it was in. It is guaranteed that between two "unplug" events there will be at least one "plug" event and vice versa, and it is also guaranteed that the first event is "unplug".

Whenever the charger is unplugged or plugged, a "U" or "P" should be shown, respectively.

In the case of our sample input, the charger is "unplugged" when the counter reaches twelve, 23 or 34 seconds and is "plugged" when the counter reaches fifteen, 28 or 67 seconds.

What, then, is the output of our example?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
U
11
10
9
P
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
U
16
15
14
13
12
P
13
14
15
16
17
18
U
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

To be clear, the first zero should not be outputted, the charger is acted on *after* the corresponding second, meaning that we wait 12 seconds *before* unplugging the charger; the 12th second does not happen after the charger is unplugged. The program runs for the highest value in the input array, in this case 67.

The question is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are not allowed here.

Comment: You should clarify that the program does not need to wait 1 second between each output (assuming that is the case). Also, title suggestion: *Battery charging tracker* or something along those lines?

Comment: @pxeger thanks for the suggestion, the program should wait 1s between each output except for the U or P indicators

Answer (score 2):

## [Quote a rational number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224292/66833)

Answer (score 2):

## [The Meeker numbers sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223366/the-meeker-number-sequence)

Comment: I've edited the draft a bit, mainly "The Challenge" section to be more in line with the standard [sequence] rules (which is what I think you were going for). I've also cleared up some of the wording. Feel free to revert/rollback if you dislike my changes

Answer (score 2):

## [R.E.P.A.I.R. T.H.E. K.E.Y.B.O.A.R.D.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223439/r-e-p-a-i-r-t-h-e-k-e-y-b-o-a-r-d)

Comment: This is a very good challenge, apart from one thing - help mode is FAR too overpowered. I could take +, * and h (in Python), and write the password as chr(1+1+1.....) +chr(1+1+1.....) and write all of the characters that way, using multiplication to ease the process. Though, without it, I think this becomes a very interesting challenge, especially for languages like Befunge-98/<><, which would be unable to do as such. An idea would be to ban +/*, or add a penalty for using it, though I'm just throwing ideas around at this point, so take my upvote.

Comment: @StackMeter i reduced help mode to take one key only

Comment: Thanks - that should cover any loopholes.

Comment: Are functions/programs allowed to share auxiliary definitions? For instance, if two of my programs need a function for (say) computing the factorial, do I count the bytes of this function once or twice?

Comment: @Delfad0r you have to write seperate programs for different keys, and so unlike your example you have two use the function twice instead of once, and it will doubled in the byte count. But don't worry its not code golf!

Comment: DISALLOW WHITESPACE!!!!!!!!! I cannot stress this enough.

Comment: @Ausername then I'd disallow deadfish~ too

Answer (score 2):

## Saboteurs in our Halls

This is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, where one member on each team attempts to sabotage their team in secret.

Similar to [Red vs. Blue - Pixel Team Battlebots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots), bots will be divided into teams, based on the user ID number of the user who posted them. Your user ID can be found by navigating to your profile (click your icon in the top bar) and looking at the URL:

```
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/[user-id]/[display-name]
```

For example, my user ID is `66833`: [`https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)

If your ID is an **even number**, then you are on the **Red team**.
If your ID is an **odd number**, then you are on the **Blue team**.
There is no way to change teams.

As you cannot change your user ID, and to prevent one team flooding the field with bots, **each user may only submit one bot**

---

### How the KotH will work

At the start of the game, each bot will be placed in a random cell in a \$1000\times1000\$ cell grid. No bot will be placed on the same cell as another bot, or within 5 cells of another bot. Additionally, \$999\$ random cells will be filled with **1 food**. These cells may be any cell on the board that doesn't contain a bot.

The aim of the game is to collect food. Each bot will navigate their way around the grid, attempting to gather food. The team with the most food at the end of the game wins.

However, one bot will actually be a *saboteur*. This bot will appear to be a member of one team, but will instead act in a manner that helps the other team. When writing your bot, you should consider the existing bots on the opposing team and try to write in a sabotage tactic that will help them without being overly obvious.

Let's say that for this specific match, the saboteur is Blue. Their actions should aim to help the Red team win, while not giving themselves away to the Blue team. If either team suspects that bot to be the saboteur, they can then act in a preventative manner towards that bot. If Blue wins, the saboteur has failed, and so will get no points when the rest of Blue does. If Red wins, then the saboteur has succeeded, and thus gets 2 points. No matter which team the saboteur is on, each member of the winning team always gets 1 point.

Which bot is the saboteur is randomly chosen at the start of the game and remains constant until the game ends. There is only ever one saboteur per game.

---

The game is broken up into *turns*. Each team acts on alternating turns, so Red moves, then Blue, then Red etc. or the other way around. Each turn, each bot will be passed a list of game data, detailed below, and will return an integer between \$1\$ and \$9\$ inclusive, indicating which direction it would like to move in:

[image]

The bot is at \$5\$ before moving.

The bots for each team are called in a random order each turn, but none of them move until they all have returned values.

After all bots in a team have returned their movement choice, all moves happen at the same time. If two bots on the same team attempt to move into the same cell, neither bot moves. If a bot tries to move out of bounds, nothing happens. If a bot moves into a cell with food, it adds that piece of food to the amount it has already gathered. Initially, all bots have gathered \$0\$ food.

If a bot moves into a cell containing an enemy bot, the two bots *fight*. The winner is determined by which bot has gathered the most food. The winner then "steals" the losers food, adding it to their total gathered food. The loser is then removed from the board and re-placed at a random location not within 5 cells of another bot, and with an initial \$0\$ food again. If both bots have the same amount of food, then both bots are removed and re-placed, and any food they had is randomly placed in empty cells around the board.

After \$10000\$ turns, the game ends. Each team has their total gathered food counted, and the team with the most food wins. The actual competition will have \$100\$ games played. If a team wins a game, each team member receives 1 point. However, if the saboteur's team (the one it's on, not the team it's helping) wins, the saboteur does not get this point. If the saboteur's team *loses*, the saboteur gains 2 points.

The team with the most total points of all its bots at the end of \$100\$ games wins.

### How to answer

You should include in your answer 2 functions: `move` and `sabotage`. `move` is the function that will be called each turn when you aren't the saboteur and `sabotage` will be called each turn that you *are* the saboteur.

Both functions will receive the same arguments:

- `x` and `y`. The `x` and `y` coordinates of your bot, each an integer between \$0\$ (top-left corner) and \$999\$ (bottom-right corner).
- `food`. The current amount of food you are carrying. Initially 0, and changed by the controller for you when necessary.
- `t_near`. A list of bots on your team within a square, side length 33 cells, centered on you. Each bot is represented by a list containing their `x` and `y` coordinates, the amount of food they're currently carrying, and the CGCC ID of their poster.
- `e_near`. A list of bots n the opposing team within a square, side length 33 cells, centered on you. Each bot is represented by a list containing their `x` and `y` coordinates, the amount of food they're currently carrying, and the CGCC ID of their poster.
- `f_near`. A list of coordinates of all food within a square, side length 33 cells, centered on you. Each food is represented by a pair `[x, y]` representing it's coordinates
- `team_chat`. A list of all chat messages sent between your team.

**Messages**

In order to allow inter-game cooperation, each team will have a "chat" ability. Each bot will be passed `team_chat`, an array containing the chat history of that team - i.e. a series of strings saying more-or-less whatever you want. The most recent message will be at the end of the array. Each bot may, on each turn, append up to 3 messages to the chat. Each message must be no longer than 100 characters, and will be prefixed with the ID of the bot who sent it (with a space after the ID).

For example, if a bot with a user ID of 1234 sent `Hello, World!` to the chat, the message would be `1234 Hello, World!`.

### Example Submission

This is Joey. Joey isn't too smart, and hasn't got the hang of proper sabotage. If not the saboteur, Joey just hunkers down and waits for the game to end. Otherwise, he moves around the board aimlessly in random directions:

```
import random

def move(x, y, food, t_near, e_near, f_near, team_chat):
	return 5

def sabotage(x, y, food, t_near, e_near, f_near, team_chat):
	return random.randint(1, 9)
```

### Rules

Any attempted gaming of the rules will lead to a disqualification of your bot. If you break any rules, your bot will be disqualified until it is fixed (if possible).

- **You may only edit your answer within 12 hours of posting** to prevent answers that continually optimise against new bots.
  You may not delete and repost your answer in order to try to circumvent this restriction
- Your code must not take longer than half a second (give or take a few milliseconds) to return its move
- You may not attempt to modify the controller or other bots' code; attempt to communicate outside of using the team chats; make web queries; or do anything malicious.

I'll keep an eye out for other unsportsmanlike behaviour, such as stealing code verbatim from other answers or using sock puppets to mess with the other team.

You are welcome to collaborate and scheme with your team, but keep the contest friendly and ethical. We don't need or want this to devolve into anarchy.

You will have 2 weeks from the posting of the challenge to submit bots. After which time, I'll run 100 games with 10000 turns each and determine the winner

---

## Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- Is this a duplicate?
- I'm not sure whether to write this in Python or Javascript. On the one hand, I'm better at Python, but Javascript is more popular/used. Thoughts?
- Tags are [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game), [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid). Suggestions?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: Very nice challenge :) Just one thing: have you considered letting bots know about the food quantity of nearby bots (in `t_near` and `e_near`)? I think it could give the saboteur a little more room to do his job (like kamikaze against enemies if they have more food than he does). Otherwise, it seems to me that there aren't many ways for the saboteur to help the enemy team, but maybe I just haven't given it enough thought.

Comment: Also, do you plan to do anything to prevent unbalanced teams (i.e. teams of different sizes)? It seems to me that having one less teammate is almost as bad as having a saboteur in your team, although this is probably because (as I said above) I still haven't found many effective strategies for the saboteur.

Comment: @Delfad0r Yeah, that sounds like a good idea, editing in the `food` suggestion for `t_near` and `e_near`. I'm not sure about dealing with unbalanced teams (it seems as though it wasn't a problem with Red vs Blue, which gives some kinda hope)

Answer (score 2):

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224000/are-all-the-items-the-same/224001#224001)

Comment: There's many challenges which have this as a subproblem, but no exact dupe I could find.

Comment: Presumably, [tag:code-golf]? And add [tag:decision-problem] [tag:array-manipulation]

Comment: Heh, lots of solutions to this exact problem were presented at [the recent APL conference](https://dyalog.tv/APLSeeds21/?v=GZuZgCDql6g).

Comment: Given how trivial this is, I'd suggest just [limiting it to digits 1 to 9](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/66833), as the overall approach isn't going to change much in list-based languages, but it'll allow string based languages (e.g. Retina) to compete better/easier. Also, as far as I can tell, this is, somehow, not a dupe

Answer (score 2):

## Draw the flag of Bangladesh

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

The flag of Bangladesh is very simple. It looks like below:

[image]

The flag will be in bottle green (#006a4e) and rectangular in size in the proportion of length to width of 10:6, with a red circle in near middle. The red circle will have a radius of one-fifth of the length of the flag. This image will help you to understand the proportions properly:

[image]

In this Graphical output challenge, you need to draw the flag of Bangladesh like first image. Standard loopholes apply, Shortest code wins.

Resolution cannot be 0px, or `echo` style answers not supported.

Minimum resolution is `286*176`

Comment: I think you need to state a minimum resolution.

Comment: @Adám what do you mean by minimum resolution?

Comment: If my output is 0px tall, then the width has to be 10×0px÷6=0px wide, and the red circle's diameter has to be 4×0px÷6=0px. Easy; here you go:

Comment: You should also specify what the colours are and/or if an exact colour match is acceptable.

Comment: Is ASCII art acceptable?

Comment: @Adám ascii art is not acceptable, also in place of bottle green (#006a4e) dark green is acceptable, if you have more flaws come to chat

Comment: You had specified the color of green background. So what is the color for the circle?

Comment: @tsh I suppose it is #f42a41

Answer (score 2):

## Make it prime with the smallest suffix

[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223564/45613)

Comment: "Your solution must work for the largest integer your language supports" If my language support integers in 0~n. Is this means my program should support all inputs in range 0~n? Or is this means my program should support all inputs when connect it with its output, the result of connection still in 0~n?

Comment: Java has support to signed 64 bit integers as `long` type. But Java also have `java.math.BigInteger` support. By saying "largest integer your language supports", does it means I must working on `BigInteger` instead of `long` or `int` types?

Comment: @tsh my intent here was that Java users would have to do that, yes. Considering that java isn't that popular of a golfing language to begin with, I'm not really concerned about the insane verbosity that brings. I am, however, considering bringing the cap to \$2^{53}-1\$ since that's the largest odd integer that can be represented with double-precision floats.

Answer (score 2):

### Decompress a Sparse Matrix (WIP)

The dual of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/129924/95792).

Decompress a sparse matrix reversing the method here [Compressed sparse row (CSR, CRS or Yale format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29).

There will be 4 inputs, either as separate variables or as a list of lists:

- `V`, a list of the nonzero elements of the matrix in row-major form. This is of length NNZ (the number of nonzero elements in the original matrix)
- `NCOLS` - the number of columns in the original matrix.
- `IA` - a list that yields the number of nonzero elements in each row in the following way: `IA[0] = 0, IA[i] = IA[i - 1] + <number of nonzero elements in row i>`. The number of nonzero elements in row i is `IA[i + 1] - IA[i]`.
- `JA` - a list of the column indices of the elements in V, also of length NNZ. (zero-indexed)

Input will be a list of 3 lists and the number of columns in the original matrix, e.g. either

```
[
  [5, 8, 3, 6],
  [0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 1],
  [4]
]
```

Or

```
V = [5, 8, 3, 6]
IA = [0, 0, 2, 3, 4]
JA = [0, 1, 2, 1]
NCOLS = 4
```

Output will be a decompressed matrix/list of lists:

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 8 0 0],
 [0 0 3 0],
 [0 6 0 0]]
```

If your language doesn't support actual data structures, input and output may be text.

#### Process

1. Create a 'matrix' of row width `NCOLS`.
2. Populate the `ith` matrix row with `N` values from `V` if the corresponding array index (`i + 1`) of `IA` is non-zero, where `N` is the `ith` element of `IA` starting at the `ith` element of `JA`.
3. repeat until V is empty
   i.e. above for the 0th matrix row `IA[1] = 0`, so this row has `NCOLS=4` zeroes in it's first row. Then for matrix row 1, `IA[2]=2` it takes 2 values from `V` starting at `JA[1]=0`. For matrix row 2, `IA[3]=3` and `IA[2]=2` so it takes the next (3 - 2 = 1) elements from `V`, starting at `JA[2]=2`. For matrix row 4  `IA[4]=4` and `IA[3]=3` so it takes the next (4 - 3 = 1) elements from `V`, starting at `JA[3]=1`.

#### Test cases

Input 1:

```
[ 5, 8, 3, 6 ]
[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 1 ]
4
```

Output 1:

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 8 0 0],
 [0 0 3 0],
 [0 6 0 0]]
```

Input 2

```
[ 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 ]
[  0  2  4  7  8 ]
[  0  1  1  3  2  3  4  5 ]
6
```

Output 2:

```
[[10 20 0 0 0 0],
 [0 30 0 40 0 0],
 [0 0 50 60 70 0],
 [0 0 0 0 0 80]]
```

Input 3:

```
[ ]
[ 0 0 0 0 ]
[ ]
3
```

Output 3:

```
[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]]
```

Input 4:

```
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 3 6 9 ]
[ 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 ]
3
```

Output 4:

```
[[1 1 1],
 [1 1 1],
 [1 1 1]]
```

Input 5:

```
[ 5, -9, 0.3, -400 ]
[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 1, ]
4
```

Output 5:

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 -9 0 0],
 [0 0 0.3 0],
 [0 -400 0 0]]
```

Assume inputs may contain any real number, you need not consider mathematical symbols or exponential representation (e.g. 5,000 will never be entered as 5e3). You will not need to handle `inf`, `-inf`, `NaN` or any other 'pseudo-numbers'. You may output a different representation of the number (5,000 *may* be output as 5e3 if you so choose).

#### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I'd suggest to at least briefly explain how the decompressing works in the post. The challenges should be self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: @bubbler, that's coming, but I need to figure out how to do that/explain it myself. I've left (WIP) on the question because of this.

Comment: @Pureferret I think it would be better to allow only nonzero integers instead of any real number. It'd be easier for most languages that way

Comment: @user I think it's more interesting seeing those languages work around those difficulties. Also the original challenge required them, so it I my makes sense this one does too.

Comment: @Pureferret I'm not sure many golfing languages support arbitrary precision floating point numbers. Would they be able to use strings, then? Edit: could you at least restrict it to rational numbers? Unlike Jon Skeet, most of us here don't know all the digits of pi :P

Comment: @user it needn't be arbitrary, just as long as it matches the test cases

Comment: @Bubbler I think the process is correct?

Answer (score 2):

## [Reject tab, return to linefeed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224595/66833)

Comment: How exactly are "printing" and "returning" distinguished? Are submissions required to be a function that also outputs to STDOUT in addition to returning a value from the function? Also, I would strongly advise against subjective criteria like having an error message related to tabs, unless they are purely for brownie points; point bonuses, especially ones that can't be judged objectively, are discouraged.

Comment: Printing and returning can be considered identical to each other for the purposes of this challenge.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 2):

## [Best Rolling Ao5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224476/best-rolling-ao5)

Comment: I'd suggest removing [rubiks-cube] and replace it with [array-manipulation and [floating-point]. I'd also recommend not requiring a trailing `0` if the output is only 1 decimal place (e.g. `28.3` for the last example) and mentioning that the sets are overlapping ("computing the ao5 for each *overlapping* set of consecutive five times")

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I want to keep the trailing zeros because that's how all times are displayed in official results. Does that make sense

Answer (score 2):

## [Sum over an Interval](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224324/sum-over-an-interval)

Comment: I'd suggest just describing the input format ("begins with either `(` or `[`, then 2 integers separated by a comma, ends with either `)` or `]`") as it's clearer. [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217297/66833), but not a duplicate. Additionally, will the input always be positive (or non-negative) integers, and will the range ever be empty?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing fixed

Answer (score 2):

## Solve the Alien Probe puzzle [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224598).

Comment: The description was clear to me, without watching either video. Doesn't seem like the wording needs much improvement.

Answer (score 2):

## [How many Faro Shuffles for a cycle?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224979) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

Comment: @Pureferret it has been!

Answer (score 2):

## [xkcd 2385](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224621/xkcd-2385-koth-final-exam)

Comment: Now that this has been posted, it should probably be edited down and deleted.

Answer (score 2):

## Drawing the Mathematics Stack Exchange logo (ASCII Logos 2)

The goal is to create the Mathematics Stack Exchange logo using ASCII characters.

It looks like this.

[image: Mathematics Stack Exchange]

The exact output should look like this:

```
                   _
                /=/ \=\
             /=/       \=\
            |             |
            |\=\       /=/|
            |   \=\ /=/   |
            |      |      |
       _    |      |      |    _
    /=/ \=\  \=\   |   /=/  /=/ \=\
 /=/       \=\  \=\|/=/  /=/       \=\
|             |    |    |             |
|\=\       /=/|         |\=\       /=/|
|   \=\ /=/   |         |   \=\ /=/   |
|      |      |         |      |      |
|      |      |         |      |      |
 \=\   |   /=/           \=\   |   /=/
    \=\|/=/                 \=\|/=/
 /=/   |   \=\           /=/   |   \=\
|             |         |             |
|\=\       /=/|         |\=\       /=/|
|   \=\ /=/   |         |   \=\ /=/   |
|      |      |         |      |      |
|      |      |    _    |      |      |
 \=\   |   /=/  /=/ \=\  \=\   |   /=/
    \=\|/=/  /=/       \=\  \=\|/=/
       |    |             |    |
            |\=\       /=/|
            |   \=\ /=/   |
            |      |      |
            |      |      |
             \=\   |   /=/
                \=\|/=/
                   |
```

You must make sure the cubes should be symmetrical just like the original logo, and must make space to create a 6-point star in the middle. Yes, the output looks messed up, but it's all I can do to really make a shape.

Remember, 6 boxes aligned as a hexagon.

Can you draw it with the least bytes possible?

---

**Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)**

Any suggestions?

If this question reaches a score of 4, it will be posted on 12:00 PM UTC, 1 month after [Stack Overflow's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22219#22219).

Answer (score 2):

## KoTH - JS WarBots

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Based on [King of the Hill: Robot Battle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/king-of-the-hill-robot-battle)

### Rules and Instructions

Program a bot as an object in JavaScript. The functions that can be called are:

- `left(name)` Moves left 1 unit (x position -1)
- `right(name)` Moves right 1 unit (x position +1)
- `up(name)` Moves up 1 unit (y position -1)
- `down(name)` Moves down 1 unit (y position +1)
- `forward(name)` Moves forward 1 unit (z position -1)
- `backward(name)` Moves backward 1 unit (z position +1)
- `mine(name)` Places a mine at current position (bots can be blown up by their own mines, with a 1 tick delay before priming)
- `scan(name)` Scans for mines and players in adjacent cells (cells a bot can move to). Returns an array `[left, right, up, down, forward, backward]`. Each element can be `0` (nothing there) `1` (mine) `2` (other bot).
- `pass(name)` Do nothing

`name` is the name of the bot. Any bot whose action's name is not the name of the bot will be disqualified (if your bot is called "Foo" you must have `pass("Foo")` and not `pass("foo")` or `pass("Bar")`)

The 3D arena is a 1000x1000x1000 cube, centered at (0,0,0). Each turn of a game, every bot must select one of the above actions to perform. Every 10 turns (subject to change) minesweeping will occur, removing 50% of the existing mines to reduce camping.

A bot is eliminated from a game if:

- It is in the same position as a mine.
- It exits the game area.
- It collides with another bot (both bots are eliminated).
- The cell that it occupies does not have integer coordinates (`(0,0,0)` is valid, `(0.5,0,0)` is not)

### Scoring

After 1000 turns, if a bot is not eliminated, it receives `Math.floor(1000/bots)` points, where `bots` is the number of bots left. If a bot eliminates another bot by mining it, it receives 100 points. If there are no bots left after 1000 turns, nobody gets any points.

### Formatting your bots

Here are examples of bots (These will be playing too!):

#### RandomBot

```javascript
var RandomBot = { // Same name as the name property
    name: "RandomBot",

    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 - 500), // If unspecified, defaults to 0.
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 - 500), // If unspecified, defaults to 0.
    z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 - 500), // If unspecified, defaults to 0.

    turn: () => {
        var action = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)
        if (action == 1) { left("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 2) { right("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 3) { up("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 4) { down("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 5) { forward("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 6) { backward("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 7) { mine("RandomBot") }
        else if (action == 8) { scan("RandomBot") }
        else { pass("RandomBot") }
    }
}
```

May the best bot win!

#### The challenge will be posted later when it receives sufficient votes and the controller is developed. If there are any questions regarding this challenge, please comment about it.

Comment: Is there anything preventing a bot from placing six mines around itself, then never moving?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Do you have any suggestions on preventing that?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've created another rule regarding camping.

Comment: I think the problem is less camping itself, and more just that I don't think there's very much strategy possible. The current restriction is trivially beatable by just enclosing yourself in a 1x1x2 space and moving back and forth.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Maybe there should be a limit on how many mines you can place?

Comment: That could lead to some interesting gameplay, but might actually make the camping problrm worse because it takes very few mines to do. I'd recommend writing a few rough bots on a sheet of paper, and running some games in your head, then seeing what makes it fun and what could use some improvement. I think there needs to be more room to do interesting things; currently there's not really much strategy beyond "don't run into mines".

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I came up with an idea regarding the issue that you brought up. There could be a minesweeper that runs every 10 or so turns where 50% of mines are removed.

Comment: I think the idea behind that is good, but it has the same problem of being easily fixable by campers, and also removing plenty of mines set up by other players.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I will consider new methods for the issues in the challenge.

Comment: Should I move this to chat?

Comment: [Sure, I moved it.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123655/discussion-between-fasterthanlight-and-redwolf-programs).

Comment: Just wondering, why use functions rather than return values? e.g. having the bot return `"left"` rather than call `left("name")`. Also, right now, this just seems like a 3D version of Robot Battle. The three-dimensionality might actually be a bad thing, though, since it makes it harder to trap bots using mines. Like Redwolf, I also encourage you to think about the rules and the strategy of the game to try to allow for more strategy, and to differentiate it from the challenge it's based off of.

Comment: Also, the camping can be reduced to scanning, going into a corner, placing three mines around you, and waiting.

Answer (score 2):

## Are You My Mother? (very WIP)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

(coincidentally, thought up around mother's day)

Oh no! All the newly-hatched ducklings have been mixed together, and they all look the same! The ducklings want to reunite with their own mother. But the mothers are also selfish and want as many ducklings as possible to go home with them. Since all the ducks look the same, the only way to tell who your mother is is by how she acts.

Your task is to write two bot algorithms: one for the mother duck and another for the ducklings.

## The game

There are 5 ducklings for each mother duck

All submissions compete at the same time

### Finding your mother

All of the ducklings line up in a 1-dimensional array in the pond, as do the mother ducks. They do not move around.

Each turn, each duck (either duckling or mother duck) can do one of the following actions:

- Do nothing
- Quack
- Flutter its wings
- Splash
- Spin around
- Shake its head
- Put its head underwater
- *some other action*

Each duckling will see the actions of each mother duck on each turn

After 20 turns, each duckling guesses which half of the mother duck array contains its mother (the upper half will get the mother duck in the middle when there are an odd number of mothers) and the process continues until each duckling has narrowed down to a single mother duck.

### Duck(ling) limitations

Ducklings are young and have poor memory. They cannot remember how long they have been lined up and can only remember the last thing each mother duck did when deciding what action to take. The only working memory available to ducklings is a single integer between 0 and 15, inclusive.

Mother ducks have a bit more memory and can remember five integers between 0 and 15, inclusive.

### Scoring

Score 1 point for each of your ducklings that went home with its mother. Score 1 point for each duckling (regardless of whose it is) that went home with your mother duck.

Comment: Controller/submission language? (suggesting ecmascript if you haven't already written one)

Comment: @Wezl yeah, probably Javascript

Comment: The narrowing logic might be a bit unfair if, say, a duckling is unsure about two ducks, but they are in different halves, while another duckling is unsure about two ducks that are next to each other, so has much more time to decide. Plus, I think, 4 bits are very little storage; I'd allow at least 16 or 32 bits, which is a bit more but still limiting.

Comment: @FZs I've considered the alternative of letting each duckling have 1-on-1 time with each mother duck, after which they can decide whether to go home with her or not. But they do not get a second chance. Not sure how to handle orphan ducklings there though.

Comment: And what if the ducklings had to return a mother index on the choice-time? Or if the ducklings had to return an *array of mother indices*, and on the subsequent turns, it'd only receive info about the ones it chose previously; finally, after *n* turns, they have to decide? These are just ideas, so you don't have to accept them as they are...

Answer (score 2):

## [Just Enough Ones](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225699/just-enough-ones)

Comment: Looks good to me. Not a big fan of OEIS questions in general, but this is one of the better ones.

Answer (score 2):

## Optimal addition subtraction chain

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225724/optimal-addition-subtraction-chain)

Comment: Maybe consider order testcases simply from -4 to 16? (Without sorted on their output length) Also, maybe add some larger testcases (no need to list all possible solutions if there are too many. maybe you can show one possible solution, and answers need to having same length output)

Comment: @tsh I can add slightly bigger test cases, but there are no known efficient algorithms to calculate it, so I'm bounded by about 100

Comment: Okay, after larger testcases added, it is not equal to https://oeis.org/A056792 now. :)

Comment: I believe that one can construct the answer without brute force search. So don't worry about it bound. It is up to you to decide if brute force search is allowed: If allowed, you may say "your program should be able to calculate answers for |n| < 100, and your algorithm should apply to any size n in theory"; If not, you could say "your program should be able to compute up to \$\pm 10^8\$ in reasonable time (not time out on tio for example)" in the question.

Comment: @tsh from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-subtraction_chain): "the determination of a minimal addition-subtraction chain is a difficult problem for which no efficient algorithms are currently known"

Comment: If i understand that statement correctly, it means an efficient (or polynomial) algorithms in \$O(P(\log_2 n))\$ is not exist. But A solution works under, say, \$O(n)\$ or maybe \$O(n^2)\$ is still possible.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm also not aware of any pseudopolynomial algorithm which solves it

Answer (score 2):

## Modify to Increment: Javascript Edition (WIP)

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

---

Your task is to insert bytes/characters into the previous answer such that it outputs the next number in sequence, spelled out in English, as its return value. The first answer must output `one`.

### Coding restrictions

Your answer's code must be *atomically irreducible*, meaning that if it is possible to remove some subset of lexical tokens from the code and have it produce the same output, then it is an invalid answer. Note that this is a distinctly different concept from removing *characters* from the code, as it treats identifiers, string literals, numbers, and operators as indivisible entities. For the purposes of this challenge, a comment is considered a lexical token, so commenting out parts of the previous answer is *not allowed* by virtue of this restriction.

Some tokens are not subject to this restriction:

- The declaration keywords `let`, `var`, and `const`
- Semicolons

Note that removing an operator between two tokens does not merge the tokens together into one token, so removing the `+` from `1+1` would result in `1 1` rather than `11`

SANDBOX NOTE: I'm debating whether this should be tightened up to character-wise irreducibility, but I'm thinking that may be too restrictive and be too difficult to chain. On the other hand, quoting and escaping into an ever-growing `.substring` call seems to be a pretty easily-exploited loophole here. Perhaps a simple bandaid solution would be to ban more than 3 consecutive backslashes. Though perhaps this isn't a problem at all because answers will be trying to make it as hard as possible to chain.

### Multi-digit spelling

For numbers above 20, the result should be spelled with multiple words. You may use spaces, hyphens, or underscores to separate words and this does not need to be consistent. (e.g. `twenty three` can be followed by `twenty-four`, and `one hundred-thirty four` is valid even though the spelling looks weird)

Should this challenge reach more than 100 answers, the expected format should be like `one hundred thirty six` rather than `a hundred thirty six`. You may optionally insert `and` between `hundred` and the next word.

### Example

Answer 1

```
_=>'one'
```

Answer 2

```
_=>'twone'.substring(0, 3)
```

Answer 3

```
_=>'threewone'.substring(0, 3+2)
```

Answer 4

```
_=>'thfoureewone'.substring(02, 3+2+1)
```

Answer 5

```
_=>'thfoureewone'.replace('our', 'iv').substring(02, 3+2+1)
```

### Rules and Scoring

- You may not comment out part or all of the previous answer.

  - This includes pseudo-commenting such as enclosing code in strings, using the comma operator to no-op parts of the code, or wrapping blocks in `if(0)`
- The case of the output does not matter (e.g. `OnE` is just as valid as `oNE`)
- No third-party libraries or vendor-specific features are allowed. The only features allowed are those found in the ECMAScript standard library as of May 14, 2021.

The first answer to go 7 days (i.e. 168 hours) without a successor is the winner.

Comment: Looks like an interesting challenge idea! I think more formally defining what "pseudo-commenting" entails would help. For example, would `[a, b][0]` be invalid? What about `0 ? a : b`? Also, I think you need to formalize what answers need to output; there are a couple different ways to spell english words. For example, is 147 "a hundred forty seven", "one hundred forty-seven", "one hundred and forty-seven"? etc.

Comment: I think an "irreducible" requirement may help this question. How should multi-digit numbers be spelled?

Comment: @Razetime Could you elaborate on irreducibility? The only thing that comes to mind is to require that the solution will not output the correct number spelled out if some subset of characters are removed

Comment: yeah that is pretty much the exact definition.

Comment: I think strict irreducibility might make it too hard to chain, though it *does* trivially ban comments and pseudo-comments.

Comment: Try `x=>'Xforty-two'.slice((function(){/* w h a t e v e r   p r e v i o u s   a n s w e r   w i t h   s p a c e s   i n s t e r e d   i n t o   e v e r y   2   c h a r a c t e r s */}+'').length===155)`

Comment: @tsh maybe irreducibility isn't the right solution. Maybe the limitation needs to be a maximum number of characters added.

Comment: An alternative would be to make adding to the solution also be atomic, so `'one'` cannot become `'twone'`

Answer (score 2):

## Convert version string to pack_format [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225916/convert-version-string-to-pack-format)

Comment: @Arnauld thanks, fixed

Answer (score 2):

## An approximation for factorials of reals

One approximation for factorial function of reals is the following function:

\$ F_0(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor ! { \lceil x \rceil } ^ { x - \lfloor x \rfloor } \$

The function is less inaccurate for higher values of \$ x \$, meaning that you can get better approximations using the following recursive definition:

\$ F_{n+1}(x-1)=\frac1x{F_n(x)} \$

Examples:

\$ F_0(\frac72)=3!\times4^{1/2}=12 \$

\$ F_1(\frac52)=12/\frac72=\frac{24}7 \$

\$ F_2(\frac32)=\frac{24}7/\frac52=\frac{48}{35} \$

\$ F_3(\frac12)=\frac{48}{35}/\frac32=\frac{32}{35} \$

\$ F_4(-\frac12)=\frac{32}{35}/\frac12=\frac{64}{35} \$

Given non-negative integer \$n\$ and real (well, floating-point) \$x>-n\$, please calculate \$ F_n(x) \$.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Bonus brownie points for using your code to approximate \$ \lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(-\frac12) \$:

\$ F_1(-\frac12)=2 \$
\$ F_2(-\frac12)\approx1.89 \$
\$ F_3(-\frac12)\approx1.85 \$
\$ F_4(-\frac12)\approx1.83 \$
\$ F_5(-\frac12)\approx1.82 \$
\$ F_6(-\frac12)\approx1.81 \$
\$ F_7(-\frac12)\approx1.80 \$
\$ F_{10}(-\frac12)\approx1.79 \$
\$ F_{18}(-\frac12)\approx1.78 \$
\$ F_{88}(-\frac12)\approx1.77 \$

Answer (score 2):

## [Symmetrical Triangles, posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226078/generate-a-mantiss-head-symmetrical-triangles)

---

### Meta Questions

- Dupe?
- More tags?
- Should I allow/disallow more output formats?
- Is "An equilateral triangle array" clear, or is there a way I can clarify it?
- Especially relevant test cases?
- Is there an easy way to take up less vertical space and still have a good amount of test cases?

Comment: This might not actually be more clear, but I think you can describe it as "output `w` lists of sizes `[1, 2, ..., w]` of 1/0s such that the total number of `1`s is equal to `n` and each sublist is a palindrome".

Comment: [tag:open-ended-function]?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino it doesn't have to have each sublist a palindrome to be symmetrical

Comment: When I first read this, I thought that it only took one input `n`, and had to output a `n`-sized triangle with `n` `1`s. Now I realise that the size is a different input, but I think it could be more interesting if `n == w`?

Comment: @pxeger I don't think that makes it more interesting, especially since it removes the point of the challenge (arranging the `1`s), by allowing them to be always placed at the bottom of the triangle.

Comment: @Wzl ah, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2):

#### Telephone Cipher Encoder

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The telephone cipher is a relatively basic cipher originating from the book The Terrible Two. The cipher is explained [here](http://terribletwo.com/welcome/#:%7E:text=You%27ve%20seen%20a%20phone,the%20position%20on%20the%20key.) as follows:

> Does this keypad (below) look familiar? It does? Good. You’ve seen a
> phone before.
>
> [image: Keypad]
>
> Now, in the telephone cipher, there are two numbers for each letter.
> The first digit corresponds to the number on a telephone, while the
> second digit corresponds to the position on the key.
>
> For example:
>
> 21 = A
>
> Why? Because A is located on the number 2 on the keypad and A
> is in the first position of that particular key.
>
> 22 = B
>
> B is located on the 2 key and is in the second position of that
> key.
>
> 53 = L
>
> L is located on the 5 key and is in the third position on that
> key.

Given an input string `s`, the program should output the string encoded with the telephone cipher.

`s` may contain single spaces between words, but will not have leading or trailing whitespace and will use only lowercase letters a-z. `s` will always have a length greater than or equal to 1.

The output should contain no whitespace and be properly encoded with the telephone cipher as described above.

As an example, the following input:

```
hello world
```

Should result in:

```
42325353639163735331
```

All [usual loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed. This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins. May the odds be ever in your favor!

Comment: What about the evens? :P

Comment: Back to the days mobile didn't have a touch screen, I typed `4433555 555666` instead of `4232535363` for `hello`...

Answer (score 2):

## Calculate \$ \lfloor n \log_2(n) \rfloor \$, exactly

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Given an integer \$ 2 \le n \$, you need to calculate \$ \lfloor n \log_2(n) \rfloor \$, assuming all integers in your language are unbounded.

However, you may not ignore floating-point errors - for example, in python `lambda n:int(n*math.log2(n))` is an invalid solution, because for example for `n=10**15`, `int(n*math.log2(n))` is 49828921423310432, while the actual answer is 49828921423310435.

### Rules

- You can assume the input is an integer \$ 2 \le n \$
- You may use any [reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed

### Test cases

```
2 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 8
5 -> 11
6 -> 15
7 -> 19
8 -> 24
9 -> 28
10 -> 33
100 -> 664
1000 -> 9965
10000 -> 132877
```

10 brownie points for beating my 4 byte 05AB1E answer.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

## [Prime Factorization - but on the exponents too](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226691/66833)

Comment: There seems to be a stray double-quote here: `"2^(2^2^2)*(3^2)`. Should it be removed, or should there be a matching one at the end?

Comment: There shouldn't be in the output - it was just to show the string format

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 2):

## [Remove All Comments From Smalltalk for Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229399/remove-all-smalltalk-comments-for-code-golf)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Duplicate?

### Edge cases?

### Not interesting/challenging?

### Tags?

Comment: May string contains `\"` as escaped characters?

Comment: I might suggest changing `\`` to a different character, simply because it's hard to use in markdown

Comment: @tsh no [;)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58011436#58011436)

Comment: Suggest testcases with multiple groups of strings, multiple groups of comments, and their combination: `"a"b"c"`, `'a'b'c'`, `a'"'b'"'c`, `a"'"b"'"c`

Comment: I'm not sure if this'd be very interesting, since it's just a matter of replacing `/"[^"]"/` if I'm correct.

Comment: @user I think there's a misunderstanding. The program must also not remove comments in strings, such as `'a"b"c'` is not changed

Answer (score 2):

## Determine Centrosymmetric String

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Let's define a centrosymmetric string as follows:

- First, add spaces to the end of each line to make the input a rectangle \$ A_{m×n} \$.
- The input is "centrosymmetric" string if and only if you get the original rectangle if you rotate the rectangle 180°. That is, it has 2-fold rotational symmetry, so \$ A_{i,j}=A_{m+1-i,n+1-j} \$ holds for all \$ A_{1\dots m, 1\dots n} \$.

### Input

Input a non-empty string. You may assume it:

- does not contain leading / trailing new lines;
- does not contain trailing spaces on any lines;
- only contains new line, space, and lowercase `a`-`z`.

You may choose to handle any of `CR`, `LF`, or `CR-LF` as the new line character in your program.

Input may be in any reasonable format, including but not limited to:

- A built-in string type;
- A NULL-terminated character array;
- An array of integer code-points;

Note that you are not allowed to take the string padded already as it trivialises the challenge.

### Output

Determine if the given input is a centrosymmetric string (as defined in this post), outputting two distinct values, or truthy vs. falsey values (they can be swapped relative to their normal meaning).

### Test cases

#### Truthy

```
a
```

```
aba
```

```
a
b
a
```

```
ab
ba
```

```
abc
cba
```

```
abc
ded
cba
```

```
a a
```

```
a

a
```

```
a

 a
```

```
a c
 b
c a
```

```
a

 b
 b

  a
```

```
zzzzz
   z
  z
 z
zzzzz
```

```
n  n  oo   oo  n  n
nn n o  o o  o nn n
n nn o  o o  o n nn
n  n  oo   oo  n  n
```

#### Falsy

```
ab
```

```
a
a
b
```

```
a
 b
a
```

```
ab
ab
```

```
aa
bb
```

```
   a
  a a
 aaaaa
a     a
```

Comment: I think a worked-through example would be a good idea

Comment: What is the meaning of the `2` in `A_{m×n}2`?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170020)

Comment: When you say "square", do you actually mean "rectangle"?

Comment: @pxeger the `2.` is accidentally left there after I remove the line break between 1. blah 2. blah. Should be removed.

Comment: @Bubbler changed to rectangle. I'm not quite sure about these words.

Comment: @tsh A square is a rectangle with all side lengths the same, so `m == n`. Sometimes in English, "square" is used as an adjective to simply mean "having right-angled corners", which is quite confusing

Answer (score 2):

## Demonstrate some easier abstract algebra

<sub>From my related challenge, [Demonstrate some advanced abstract algebra](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22398/66833)</sub>

Consider a binary operator \$*\$ that operates on a set \$S\$. For simplicity's sake, we'll assume that \$*\$ is closed, meaning that its inputs and outputs are always members of \$S\$.

Let's define some basic terms describing the properties of \$*\$. We can say that \$*\$ can have any of these properties, if they hold for all \$a,b,c \in S\$:

- **Commutative**: \$a*b = b*a\$
- **Associative**: \$(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)\$
- **Distributive**: \$a*(b+c) = (a*b)+(a*c)\$, for some binary operator \$+\$ on \$S\$

We can also define 3 related properties, for a unary operation \$-\$ on \$S\$:

- **Anti-commutative**: \$a*b = -(b*a)\$
- **Anti-associative**: \$(a*b)*c = -(a*(b*c))\$
- **Anti-distributive**: \$a*(b+c) = -((a*b)+(a*c))\$

Finally, we define 3 more, that only describe \$*\$ if the complete statement is true for \$a,b,c \in S\$:

- **Non-commutative**: There exists \$a, b\$ such that \$a*b \ne b*a\$ and \$a*b \ne -(b*a)\$
- **Non-associative**: There exists \$a, b, c\$ such that \$(a*b)*c \ne a*(b*c)\$ and \$(a*b)*c \neq -(a*(b*c))\$
- **Non-distributive**: These exists \$a,b,c\$ such that \$a*(b+c) \ne (a*b)+(a*c)\$ and \$a*(b+c) \ne -((a*b)+(a*c))\$

We now have 9 distinct properties a binary operator can have: commutativity, non-commutativity, anti-commutativity, associativity, non-associativity, anti-associativity, distributivity, non-distributivity and anti-distributivity.

This does require two operators (\$-\$ and \$+\$) to be defined on \$S\$ as well. For this challenge we'll use standard integer negation and addition for these two, and will be using \$S = \mathbb Z\$.

Obviously, any given binary operator can only meet a maximum of 3 of these 9 properties, as it cannot be e.g. both non-associative and anti-associative.

---

Let's create a "table" of these properties:

|  | Commutative | Associative | Distributive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Regular** | Commutative | Associative | Distributive |
| **Anti** | Anti-commutative | Anti-associative | Anti-distributive |
| **Non** | Non-Commutative | Non-associative | Non-distributive |

Your task is to write 3 programs (either full programs or functions. You may "mix and match" if you wish).

Each of these 3 programs will:

- take two integers, in any reasonable format and method
- output one integer, in the same format as the input and in any reasonable method
- be non-constant. That is, there exists at least two distinct inputs that have distinct outputs.
- have exactly 3 of the 9 above properties. However, those three properties muse be in different rows and columns in the above table from each other. This means that it can be (for example) commutative, non-associative, anti-distributive; non-commutative, anti-associative, distributive; or anti-commutative, associative, non-distributive. But, it cannot be (for example) commutative, associative, distributive; non-commutative, non-associative, non-distributive; or non-commutative, anti-distributive, anti-associative.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); the combined lengths of all 3 of your programs is your score, and you should aim to minimise this.

Additionally, you should include some form of proof that your programs do indeed have the required properties and do not satisfy the other properties. Answers without these are not considered valid.

Alternatively, a proof of impossibility is a valid answer. If you can demonstrate that there are no such programs that satisfy the criteria listed above, then this proof constitutes a valid answer as well.

---

## Meta

- This is pretty math-heavy, is it clear?
- Is this a dupe?
- Tags are [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra). Any others?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: There [exists no](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229808/86301) anti-distributive surjection when \$S=\mathbb Z\$. Maybe there exists one when \$S=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^k\$, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I would remove the constraint that the operator be a surjection, and just impose that it be non-constant. If you convince yourself that such an anti-distributive operator exists, you could post the challenge, but I would change it to "write 3-9 programs, such that each property is verified by (at least) one program". That would be an incentive to have programs which verify several properties at once, but make it more manageable.

Comment: Also, there are problems with your "anti-associativity": if b = 1, then `(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)`.

Comment: @RobinRyder If \$ S=(\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z)^k\$, aren't anti-distributive operators the same as distributive operators?

Comment: @Nitrodon Yes, of course you are right.

Answer (score 2):

## Decode USB packets [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [coding-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory) [encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoding)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229375/decode-usb-packets)

Answer (score 2):

## Combinatorial Pipes

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [combinations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinations)

You're a plumber working on a house, and there's some pipes that must be connected at odd angles. You have 8°, 11.25°, 22.5°, 45°, and 90° fittings at your disposal, and you want to use as few as possible to match the angle as closely as possible.

## Goal

- Match the desired angle as closely as possible, with as few fittings as possible.  It can be over or
  under the desired angle.
- Accuracy is more important than the number of fittings
- In the case of two different sets of fittings with the
  same resulting angle, whichever has the fewest number of fittings should be selected.
- If the two sets use different fittings, match the same
  angle, and have the same number of fittings, either may be chosen.

## Input

Your input is a random integer between (non-inclusive) 0 and 180, which represents the desired angle.

## Output

Your output should be an array where [0]-># of 8° fittings, [1]-># of 11.25° fittings, etc. If your language does not support arrays, you may output a comma separated list, where the first value represents the number of 8° fittings, and so on and so forth.

**Test Cases**

```
90° ->[0,0,0,0,1]
24°-> [3,0,0,0,0] ([0,0,1,0,0] uses less fittings, but is less accurate and therefore incorrect)
140°->[2,1,2,0,1]
140°->"2,1,2,0,1" acceptable if language does not support arrays
```

## Scoring

Lowest byte count for each language wins a high five from me if we ever bump into each other (and the challenge).

### Sandbox Questions

Howdy! I feel like this could be an interesting golf, but I'm unsure if the language is clear and concise enough to get the idea across.

Comment: Might be interesting to make it more general, give a list of possible pipe fittings as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Comment: Does this not basically boil down to base-conversion?

Comment: @pxeger Base conversion will not work.  For one base conversion generally ignores leading zeros, while `00010 /= 10`, so its not a bijection. But even if you ignore that it's nowhere near monotonic. `11 > 100` but `f(11) = 10 < 11 = f(100)`.

Answer (score 2):

## Is there a left-right connection?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-matrix) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

### Task

Given a square array of 0s and 1s, determine whether or not there exists a path of 1s connecting the leftmost and rightmost columns.  A path can take steps of one unit up, down, left or right, but not diagonally.  Every symbol on the path must be a 1, and it must start somewhere in the first column and end somewhere in the last column.

Shortest code in each language wins.

### Examples

```
000
111   ->  True
111

110
110   ->  False
110

101
010   ->  False
101

0     ->  False

1     ->  True

11110
00010
01110 ->  True
01000
01111

11110
00010
01100 ->  False
01000
01111
```

### Notes

The array may be represented in any reasonable form, such as a list of lists `[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` or a string `'000 111 111'`.  It can optionally be in transposed form (so that the roles of rows and columns are exchanged; equivalently the code can instead determine whether there is a top-bottom connection). Any two distinct symbols can be used in place of 0 and 1.  The output can be in any truthy/falsy form.

Answer (score 2):

## Consecutive Distance Rating [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229724/consecutive-distance-rating)

Comment: This is really neat! Simple, elegant, but nontrivial. It'd be interesting to look at the sum and its growth given an (OEIS) sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Title: Make a WebCrawler dictionary writer.

Notice: for any text within <> tags, please ignore any .'s. These are simply added so that they are treated as plain text, and not code.

Your goal is to make a program that acts as a regular WebCrawler, but also writes a dictionary using the websites.

You should have a list that is used to store words that have been added called Dictionary, and another list to store website urls called NextSites. You should also have a variable called sites, and a variable called input2. Any other variables or lists are optional.

It should ask for input upon running the program, allowing you to input a website url, from where it will start web crawling. How it asks for input does not matter, so long as you are able to use any website as input. It should then ask for input again, allowing you to chose how many sites it should continue for. The variable much should be set to this input.

Next, it should check the website for any text contained within <.p> tags. It should separate the text contained within the tag at any space contained in it. Next, it will compare each part that has been separated against the current text in the list used to store words. Any part that is not already in the list should be added to it.

After it has checked all of the text within the <.p> tags on the site, it should check for any <.a> tags on the site. Any urls that it finds in the 'href' part of the <.a> tag should be added to the website url list, so long as the url list is not larger than 99 urls. (This means that the maximum amount of urls that can be in the url list at any one time is 100).

When all of the <.a> tags on the site have been checked for urls, it should change the current site it is on to the first site in the list of urls. It should remove this url from the list, and move all other urls to the spot one less than them on the list, so that there is no empty space at the beginning. (eg: If you had 3 urls: 1. google.com , 2. wikipedia.com , 3.stackexchange.com, then after switching to google.com, the list would now be 1. wikipedia.com , 2.stackexchange.com .)

It should then repeat the above steps, and continue to do so until the variables sites and much are the same.

Next, it should should output the entire list of words that it found. The method used to output it does not matter, so long as all words in the list are outputted, with a new line for each word.
E.g.: You may have found the words cat, mouse, and food. The output would look as follows:

cat

mouse

food

Scoring: The scoring follows regular code golf rules. The person with the smallest program in bytes wins. However, in the case of a tie between two programs, the program that can webcrawl and write the dictionary starting on wikipedia.com for 100 sites fastest will win.

Comment: running this type of program even once would probably ends up throttling the sites and blocking access to the crawler. Is there a good way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw an Ascii Grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229979/draw-an-ascii-grid)

Comment: You can use this to visualise a tictactoe game -- might just do that.

Comment: Looks great, just leave it for another 2 days before posting!

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement a cleave function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230145/implement-a-cleave-function)

[functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: @Adám You're right. Thanks!

Comment: If my language can directly apply a list of functions to a number, giving me a list of results, does that mean a 0-byte answer, or do I have to wrap the application in no-op code?

Comment: @Adám I have no idea if there's a precedent for 0-byte answers, but if the mere act of writing a list of functions immediately applies them to some object in your programming language, that's interesting and I would want to see it. Would writing a blurb about builtins/builtin behavior being allowed help? Something like "Builtin functionality is allowed but consider adding a less trivial answer as well."?

Comment: Yes, that would help, and asking for non-trivial things is nice. You might also want to ask for people to explain.

Comment: @Adám Added, thanks.

Comment: While tagged [tag:functional-programming], are we still allowed to submit a full program that prompts for \$L\$ and \$n\$?

Comment: @Adám I'm not sure. I took a look at some other higher-order function questions for inspiration, for example [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223881/implement-an-over-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223881/implement-an-over-function) and it uses the language "You may input and output in the most convenient format for your language, and in any convenient method,..." and that seemed to suffice there.

Comment: Funny thing is that while you call it a conceptual inverse of map, it is just a map, right? E.g. in JS: `(L,n)=>L.map(f=>f(n))`

Comment: Indeed, it can be written in *terms* of map. Does it seem too trivial, you think? Does it need spicing up?

Comment: No, I think it is great.

Comment: How would one apply a list of functions to a number in something like Python, which is not a functional-programming language

Comment: @StackMeter `lambda l,n:map(lambda f:f(n),l)`

Comment: I see now, thanks @RecursiveCo.

Answer (score 2):

## Largest Number with No Repeating Digit Pairs

*Inspired by [the problem with the same name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110490/largest-number-with-no-repeating-digit-pairs)  on [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com).*

You are to find the largest number that only uses every digit pair once, in a given base. For example, in ternary we have 2212011002. We can do this greedily by simply starting with the  largest number, and then adding the next largest number we can without repeating a pair, until we’ve gotten them all.

**Challenge:** Given a base from 1-10, output the largest number in that base with no repeating digit pairs.

As long as the digits make the number, you may output with anything, or nothing, in between. Whether regularly delimited, or irregularly gibberished.

You may also take input in any reasonable way. For example, you might take the base, the max digit, or an ordered list representing the digits available. For octal, this would mean  `8`, `7` or `76543210`. If you feel like a challenge, you can take `octal` as input. I won't complain!

Note that it need only work for bases from 1-10. Invisible points for doing alphanumeric bases like hex, but not at all required.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least bytes *per language* wins.

##### Test Cases

```
Decimal: 10
99897969594939291908878685848382818077675747372717066564636261605545352515044342414033231302212011009


Octal: 8
77675747372717066564636261605545352515044342414033231302212011007


Quaternary: 4
33231302212011003


Ternary: 3
2212011002


Binary: 2
11001


Unary: 1
00
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest this be able to support even higher bases, up to 36 maybe.  Though that might give some languages that have built-in support for higher number bases an unfair advantage?  Because other languages might have to add special support for A = 9 + 1 rather than just using the ASCII values.  Maybe just base 26, and use *only* letters, no numbers?  Not sure if it's worth bothering...  (Ah, I see you added that note after I posted this comment)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I did add the edit to make the question as is clearer, but whether or not to include higher bases is precisely my one hang-up! That's what we're discussing in [TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). Come join us!

Answer (score 2):

## Play Thud

Thud is a game described by Terry Pratchett in his novel, Thud!.

The game simulates a battle between the Dwarfs (in blue) and the Trolls (in green) on an
octagonal board with the Thudstone (an impassable space) in the centre of the board.

[image: Thud board]

I have created an environment to play the game and develop game playing code at: https://ajfaraday.github.io/Thud/dist/index.html

The challenge is to write the most successful dwarf or troll player of this game (these will be two separate challenges).

## Rules

Starting with the Dwarfs, players take it in turns to move.

### Dwarf Movement

On the Dwarf player's turn, they can move one dwarf piece either as a walk or a hurl.

*Walk*: Dwarfs can move as far as they like in any direction until they hit an obstacle
(another dwarf, the edge of the board, or a troll).
They can only kill a troll by walking if they are only one space away.

*Hurl*: If two or more dwarfs are in a line (horizontal, vertical or diagonal), they can hurl the dwarf on the end of the line, by
the length of the line (e.g. in a line of 3, the dwarf on the end can be hurled 3 spaces).
If a dwarf is hurled into a troll, the troll is killed, reducing the trolls score by 4 points.

### Troll Movement

On the Troll player's turn they can  move one troll piece, either as a walk or a shove.

*Walk*: Trolls can move one space in any direction, unless a troll, dwarf or the edge of the
board is in the way. Whenever a troll moves, it kills all dwarfs adjacent to
it's destination space.

*Shove*: If two or more trolls are in a line (horizontal, vertical or diagonal) they can shove the troll
at the end of the line that number of spaces away, but *only* if any of the target space's immediate
neighbours contain a dwarf. When a troll is shoved, it kills all dwarfs on or adjacent to
it's destination space.

It is not permitted for a troll to land directly on a dwarf by either walk or shove moves.

Each dwarf killed reduces the dwarfs score by 1 point.

### Scores

The score is calculated thus:

- The dwarf player has one point for every dwarf remaining on the board.
- The troll player has four points for every troll remaining on the board.
- The key figure is the difference between these two. This will be used to calculate
  players' scores in the tournament.

### Ending the game

The game ends when any of these conditions is met:

- There are no dwarfs on the board.
- There are no trolls on the board.
- Both players have declared the game over.
- The game has reached it's cut-off length of 500 moves.

## How to manually play a game

- Go to https://ajfaraday.github.io/Thud/dist/index.html
- Hover the mouse over a piece to see it's available moves.
- - Safe moves are outlined in green.
- - Dangerous moves (which can be killed the next turn) are outlined in orange.
- - Killing moves are highlighted in red when the mouse hovers over them.
- Click a piece to select it for the current move.
- Click one of the available moves to move the piece.
- (You can click the relevant 'Make Peace' button to declare the game over according to that player, during their turn)

## How to set up a local instance of the game

You don't have to clone the repository and use it locally to  to create an entry, but it helps.

- `git clone git@github.com:AJFaraday/Thud.git`
- `cd Thud`
- `npm install`
- You can then run `./get_answers.sh` to get the latest entries from Stack Exchange

If you prefer, you can use the github pages instance at https://ajfaraday.github.io/Thud/dist/index.html

## How to customize a game

- Open /dist/index.html in your browser
- Click 'Customize'
- Select troll and dwarf clients (manual allows direct control)
- Select a turn time in milliseconds (only relevant to non-manual players)
- Click 'Run Game' to see or play the game.
- (Clicking 'Close' will not enact any changes)

## Clients

The game is played by clients, which represent either a troll or a dwarf player. Each is a
JavaScript class which must have these three functions:

- `constructor(controller)` - controller is an object which acts as your interface with the game (see below).
- `turn()` - This is called whenever it is your players turn to move.
- `end_turn()` - This is called after your player's turn is over. It can not move pieces, but can make
  decisions on whether or not to declare the game over.

### Controller

The `controller` object is your client's interface with the game itself. You can find full documentation
for the controller class here: https://github.com/AJFaraday/Thud/blob/main/docs/controller_interface.md

It provides these methods to interrogate the state of the game:

- `turn()` - Current turn of the game
- `scores()` - The current score
- `spaces()` - Every space, and what's in it
- `space_info(x, y)` - Detailed information on any space on the board.
- `dwarves()` - The location of every dwarf
- `trolls()` - The location of every troll
- `pieces()` - All pieces belonging to the current player (equivalent of `dwarves()` or `trolls()`)
- `indexed_dwarves()` - The location of every dwarf with a fixed index
- `indexed_trolls()` - The location of every troll with a fixed index
- `previous_move()` - What got moved to where last turn
- `killing_moves()` - All moves which can kill one or more opponent
- `current_space` - Currently selected space (not a function)
- `clear_space()` - Empties currently selected space
  These methods are used to actually make your move:
- `check_space(x, y)`- Find out what moves are available from a given space
- `select_space(x, y)` - The player decides to move a piece at space.
- `check_move(x, y)` - Find out what will happen if you move to a place
- `move(x, y)` - The player moves the current piece to the selected space.

These are concerned with ending the game:

- `declare(game_over)` - Say whether or not your player thinks the game is over.
- `opponent_declared()` - Has the opponent declared the game over?

## How to write a client

Warning: There is an issue with the project on Firefox (https://github.com/AJFaraday/Thud/issues/3)
which prevents editing the code in the browser. This has been confirmed to work in Chrome.

- Open 'dist/index.html' in your browser.
- Click 'Customize'.
- Select 'dwarf/template' as the Dwarf player (or use another client as a starting point).
- Click 'Edit' beside the Dwarf player select.
- Write your client code in the text box provided.
- The Validate button will change colour based on whether or not the client is passes validations (see below).
- When you're happy with it, click 'Apply' (This can be done before it passes validation, but it may not actually work).
- Select a worthy opponent and click 'Run Game' to see the game.

### Validations

In order for a client to work, and therefore be enterable in the challenge, it has to pass these
validations:

- It must evaluate as Javascript code.
- The code must return a class, with a constructor which accepts one argument.
- Instances of this class should have functions named `turn()` and `end_turn()`
- The client must play a game until it is over (i.e. it must call a valid `move` during every `turn` call).
  The validator will run games against default opponents to determine if this happens.
- Does not have any forbidden terms
  ** `game.` - Only interact with the game via controller
  ** `Math.random` - Please keep it deterministic
  ** `setTimeout` or `setInterval` - Keep it sequential
  ** `eval`, `require` or `import` - Just don't

You can open the developer console (F12) to see more detailed information on your client's
validation process.

### How to save a client

If you have cloned the git repository, you can save your entry for future tinkering. This
step is not required for entry in the challenge, but it may be helpful.

- Edit a client, as above.
- When you're happy with it (preferably if it's passing validation, too), click 'Copy' from the edit interface.
- Create a .js file in `/src/clients/dwarf/entry` with the name of your entry e.g. `/src/clients/dwarf/entrygreat_dwarf_player.js`.
  (This folder will not be wiped by `get_clients.js`)
- Run `node script/get_clients.js` from the Thud directory to make your entry available from
  the Dwarf player select. You only need to do this once to make it avilable.
- `npm run build` - this will keep watching for changes in your entry and updating the package.

### How to enter your client in the competition

- Decide on the name of your client, your client_name must only have alpha characters and underscores.
- Answer this question with your entry

  - The first line of your answer should be your client's name as a title (with = characters under it on the second line)
  - There should be a code block containing the class for your entry (with or without the preceeding `module.exports =`)
  - After that please include a brief explanation of your client's behaviour, and any other information you'd like to include.

Once this is in place, anyone running `./get_answers.sh` will see your client available under your username.

The GitHub Pages instance will also be updated periodically. So by making an entry, your code
will be added to the repo.

## Tournament rules

The tournament will pit every available dwarf client (in `/src/clients/dwarf/`) against
every available troll client (in `/src/clients/troll/`), and each pairing will play
exactly one game.

The *difference* between the two players' scores will then update a running total
for each client. The winner will gain the difference, and the loser will lose the difference.

There are two winners in the tournament, the most successful troll player and the most
successful dwarf player.

According to the rules, after playing a game, the players swap sides, so please also write an entry on the
Troll challenge.

[asymmetrical](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetrical) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)  [javasctript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javasctript)

---

This is now nearly complete (apart from some UI improvments and presenting the tournament results a bit more nicely). There's a working example of the code importer working against these two meta questions:

- Dwarf: [Stack Exchange API Sandbox (dwarf edition)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23642/stack-exchange-api-sandbox-dwarf-edition)
- Troll: [Stack Exchange API Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18632/stack-exchange-api-sandbox)

I could really use someone to attempt an end-to-end run at creating a client and adding it to one of these to check that my instructions are clear and everything works.

Comment: Very well described challenge. Seems nice!

Comment: @EliteDaMyth Thank you for taking a look. Glad it looks complete.

Comment: Two rule questions: 1. in which direction can be hurled/shoved? 2. `It is not permitted for a troll to land directly on a dwarf by either walk or shove moves.` but both troll moves have lines like `kills dwarfs on … destination`/`…only if the target space … contains a dwarf`.

Comment: @xash Good questions, I'll update to be clear. The answer is always 8 directions vertical, horizontal and diagonal. Also, I learned about the rule that trolls can't land on anything after writing the rules. I should have updated the steps too

Answer (score 2):

## [Convert codepoint to UTF-9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237315/convert-codepoint-to-utf-9)

Comment: For clarity, I'd start octal constants with `0o`. Also, an explanation of how UTF-9 works should probably be included here.

Comment: Could you include the basic algorithm to encode UTF-9 in your post instead of require an external resource? So this question can be made self contained.

Comment: @tsh Should I do with actual program source or in pseudo code?

Comment: first challenge that made me LOL

Answer (score 2):

## [When's my weekend finally here?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230307/whens-my-weekend-finally-here)

Answer (score 2):

## On a Collapsing Platform

### Rules

In this KoTH, your task is to not die. It seems simple, right? Well, no.

You're on a platform. A giant platform, of size `100 * (entries) ^ 1.1` units across (this may change if we get a lot of entries). And every few turns, a random tile is removed. As well as this, you, not a small mass in the scale of things, can cause a tile to fall down. Let me explain how this works.

You (the entrant to this KoTH) control a certain number of bots. You (the bots) can then move around on the platform and try not to die. You (still the bots) can move up to 10 units away at base, and can see up to 100 units away (units will be called u from now). However, jumping over a hole costs 2u more, meaning that the largest gap you can clear is three units (3 * 3 for the gap and 1 to land). Do not try and clear 4u+ gaps; *you will die*. Going off the edge of the platform also is an unwise choice - *you will die*.

By "you - not a small mass in the scale of things", I mean to say that every step you take takes you closer to your inevitable death - each tile you step on has a hidden durability stat, that will not be revealed to you during the course of the round. When it hits 0, the unlucky bot (hopefully not you (the bot)) on it will be removed with the tile. Do not do this; *you will die*.

Your weight is a random stat that is decided at the start of your game, and is subtracted from a tile's durability each time you step on it (weights are 150 at base, and durability values in the range of `15000 - 45000 * (entrants) ^ 1/2`, or 15000 * `1-3 * entrants ^ 1/2`, so it only becomes an issue in the long term, or when a lot of players exist.) Do not forget about this and start camping on the same 10 tiles on the end; *you will die*.

Everything takes place on a tick system - every 10 ticks, you can do an action (subject to change to 20ish if this is exploitable) and this may well be the most important part of the game - reduce it at all costs - the fewer ticks you waste, the less durability you take off, and the longer you can thread the needle between life and death. Do *NOT*, and I mean *NOT* in caps, forget about this - ***you will die***.

There are a few items that you can get that will improve your chances and delay your inevitable death represented by these characters:

`-`: Removes 1-7% of your weight (or 1-7, whichever is lesser)

`=`: Increases your speed by 1 (at 13, this will in fact, prove me wrong and let you clear 4u jumps - still not got the + though).

`?` Increases vision by 5 (allowing you to see 5 more blocks in either direction.

`>` Reduces your tick delay by 0.1 or 1% of your tick rate, should it drop below 5 (however, before that, *you will die* most likely.)

`+` Duplicates the bot - you start with 10 bots, and each bot left over at the end is worth 10 000 points (1 per tick survived), so this can, effectively, give you 10 000 points free.

Every 10-25 turns, a random platform is removed - unless necessary, this will not drop any bots - the platform chosen will always be empty (just so people don't get unlucky and die at turn 85) unless it is forced not to be - for example, in the endgame, where there is only 10 tiles left. Do not forget this; *you will die*

### Input and Output

To begin with, you will get a string such as this

`0, 111, 132, 122, 133, 211, 201, 212, 233, 310, 323`, where:

The first number represents your unique player id, known as PID in the it gang. Then, you get 10 numbers, representing your bots' start positions.

Then, for each turn, for each bot that did not die, you (the player) get a string such as this (shortened to save space):

`.___.+>-__u__...+>+-_._`

representing the bot's vision.

You must then return an integer, representing how many units you wish to move forward (negative is backwards) (and do not forget that spaces take 2u more, or *you will die*.); do not try and move more than your speed, or it will be modulo-ed. Errors and invalid input return 0. Note, spaces are represented with `.`, in the examples and in game.

### Helper functions (to delay your death, hopefully until the end):

`info()`: gives you a chunk of info, in this format:

```
PID: 0
Bots: 11
Score: 10000
[
BID: 1
Weight: 97
Speed: 12
Tick Delay: 8.8
Vision: 110
Pos: -932
Score: 830
]

[
BID: 3
...
]
```

The string is format as such:

- First, your unique PID.
- Then, the number of bots you still have.
- Then, your total score.
- Then, for each bot:

  - Its bot ID (or BID for the it gang). (Note, BID are cannot be reassigned, so if Bot 2 dies, and then Bot 1 duplicates, it will have a BID of 10, not 2 (also we count from 0) as it would be if they were.)
  - Its weight, speed, tick delay and vision, in that order.
  - Its position on the platform, in that order.
  - Its score.

`position()`: gives a position of every bot, ordered by their bot ID, or BID (again, only for the it gang).

`position(ID)`: gives the x position for a bot with a specific ID. If that ID has died already, it will return "Dead" - plus the space where it died. If that bot never existed, it will return `None`.

`tickdelay(), weight(), speed(), vision(), tickdelay(ID), weight(ID), speed(ID), vision(ID):`

Does exactly what it says on the tin, returns that specific stat for all bots if no ID is given, or the one with that ID should it be given (again, if the bot is dead, it just returns its stats on the turn it died, and if it never existed, it returns `None`. Make of it what you will).

`vision(ID)` Gives a specific bot's vision - this is useful for sketching a map of the world in conjunction with `position(ID)`. Note that other bots are represented as `s`, so if you're lucky enough to get your bot (`u`) in between two opposing bots (`s`), feel free to laugh.

You are allowed access to ALL the random functions (apart from `random.seed()`, however I will use a set of predetermined seeds in a random order to facilitate retesting. There will be a large number of trials done - this is just to aid improvements if you so desire to make them.

Bots can store variables and write to files, but ONLY in their directory. I will find any bot who does this and ban them.

### Scoring

Bots gain 1 point for each turn they survive, increasing by 1 every 100-200 turns. This will be notified with the string `Score/turn increased by 1`. Every powerup gives +500, except for `+`, which duplicates the bot, *including its score*, thus adding its score to your total. At the end, when there is three or fewer tiles left, you gain 10000 + the bot's current score for each bot left alive. This is done for every bot that lives, so people getting 2 or more bots through gain more than those getting 1, and two opposing bots can both get points for their team.

At least 10000 games will be run per round (subject to change), each time resetting all the stats to the base, rerolling RNG and restarting from the beginning.

After as many rounds as I can get through on my PC, the scores will be added up, and the winner gets an accept.

## Meta

Help with a Python controller would be appreciated.

Any specifications need to be made?

Should I edit any formulae?

Answer (score 2):

## [The Great Betting Game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230689/100690)

Answer (score 2):

## [Print this sequence I just made up](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230677/print-this-sequence-i-just-made-up)

Comment: Your test cases are correct. (Confirmed with an ungolfed integer implementation.)

Comment: _Your code must not fail due to floating point errors._ If the language used doesn't have arbitrary-precision integers, an integer implementation may fail because of integer overflow _before_ a floating point implementation fails. :-/

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for confirming my testcases. Would saying that you cannot use floats work?

Comment: I think the current wording is fine. It's just weird that prohibiting floating point errors is likely to lead to integer implementations that are actually worse.

Comment: @Arnauld Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## Generate off-by-one regex for a string

Given an alphanumeric string as input, generate JS-flavored regex in order to match any off-by-one errors for that string. In stricter terms, your resulting regex must match any single deletions, single replacements, or single additions like in the below examples.

##### Examples:

```
"hi" -> "(h|i|.i|h.|.hi|h.i|hi.)"
"golf" -> "(olf|glf|gof|gol|.olf|g.lf|go.f|gol.|.golf|g.olf|go.lf|gol.f|golf.)"
```

[Here](https://tio.run/##rZHBCsIwDIbP61OEnFqmg@FtsCcZOwjLZqRmo6ug4LvXtlM8eRA8heb7kw/S5e5PsxxCGGgET6vXq2lU4WiiG7SAGlUxzg4YWMAdZSJtSWIopQpPlyWmLOe52BjIQmp23H8wYnWeWXR6ptC2vGxzEkrAx2@SlyBtrvAfmgjr76qKZSXnNe@Sz/wofF8y167Z130iJhN/dbIBpRbH4nX@AZxmO6IxITwB) is a program for generating the results.

Note: The order of the regex does not need to matter (ie, "hi" could be "(h|h.|hi.| . . .")) so long as all patterns are in the regex.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) [regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)

Comment: Which flavor of regex will be used?

Comment: @user Lets go with JS to make it consistent, it shouldn't really matter though as the regex will share the exact same format as the example cases, with only the order possibly changed. However, i've now updated the post for clarity.

Comment: May string contains special characters like `.[]$^(?!)\\`?

Comment: Your regexp for input `hi` also match `hi` itself, which is not off-by-one. Is this designed behavior?

Comment: @tsh for question 1, ill specify alphanumeric, and for question 2, ill keep it as intended just so it doesn't needlessly complicate the question, but if you have a simple way to implement it, be my guest

Answer (score 2):

## [Snap (card game)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235064/94346)

Answer (score 2):

## [Are you a probabilist or a physicist?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231734/are-you-a-probabilist-or-a-physicist)

Comment: Is it fine to be a function in one language and a full program in another?

Comment: "Your programs should be true polynomials" - did you mean poly*glots*?

Comment: @Bubbler Yep, that's fine

Comment: @pxeger No, clearly you should code mathematical functions involving powers, multiplications and additions to solve this ;) Typo fixed

Answer (score 2):

## [Calculate the integer square root of a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233007/66833)

Comment: Should really be "Calculate the integer square root of a matrix", because there acan be multiple square roots. E.g. `[[18, 63], [14, 67]]` also has as square root, the given solution divided by 11.

Comment: I think it should be "Calculate an integer square root of a matrix", since "the integer square root" is the language you would use if there were only one.  If you find combining "Calculate" with "an" a bit awkward, you could substitute "Determine" or "Find".

Answer (score 2):

## Pinpoint the typo!

#### Task

Write a program that finds the location of an error in its own code!

The program itself must output either nothing or an empty string (or an appropriate equivalent in your language).

Let n be the length of the program in bytes, which must be at least 2.  For an integer k with 1<=k<=n, if the kth byte of the source code is deleted, then the resulting program should output the integer k (and nothing else), in as many cases as possible.

Outputs may be 0-indexed if preferred, so that omitting the kth byte outputs k-1, but the choice of indexing must be consistent across all k.

Error messages do not count as valid output unless they are of exactly the required form.

Your score is the number of integers k for which the above condition is satisfied, divided by n.  Highest score wins, with ties broken by smallest n.

#### Example

Consider the program `blob()` in a fictitious language.  Suppose that:

`blob()` outputs nothing (this is a requirement)

`lob()` outputs `1` (right)

`bob()` outputs `2` (right)

`blb()` outputs `3` (right)

`blo()` outputs `4` (right)

`blob)` outputs nothing (wrong)

`blob(` outputs `6: Syntax error` (wrong)

Then the score would be 4/6 = 0.66666667

Comment: This *might* be abused by simply making a very long answer.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107643/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/180257/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154286/66833)

Comment: @user Yes, I did wonder about that, although such answers might still be interesting.  Ideas for a better scoring system?  Number of 'wrong' answers is not great, because of very short answers....

Comment: What I did with my 'Quantum quine' question, which is similar, is for the scoring system count the number of chars that it *doesn't* work for.

Comment: @emanresu A The problem I see with that is that very short programs would get an unreasonable advantage.  E.g. any 4-byte program that does nothing gets 4 without even trying to accomplish the task...

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if the unaltered program must output Hello World or something...

Comment: @aeh5040 I also ruled that each answer had to have at least one functional result... Then again, quines do have to be at least a certain size. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

## IATA Airport Codes [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

Out of **17576** alphabetical triplets, to this day, **9144** are used as [IATA airport codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code).

Given a 3-letter string, tell whether it appears in [***the list***](https://gist.github.com/UHJ5cCdqYXQn/a348d02d64805053d26728511aefc923).

- The **input** string is *mixed-case* by default, but you can restrict it to *non-mixed-case* or *lower-case* or *upper-case*
- To **output** the affirmative/negative outcome you should use:

  - truthy/falsy according to your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
  - one consistent value as either affirmative or negative, and any other value as the other
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sub>*The list was scraped from [iata.org](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/) on 2021-08-07*</sub>

### Meta

- Is there something that needs to be specified/clarified?

Comment: What is *uniform case*? Add the [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] tag since there's a limited input domain? [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com) is an alternative that's well-trusted by this community, I'd say

Comment: @pxeger I want to say a string where all the letters are uppercase or lowercase, contrary to mixed-case

Comment: @pxeger maybe *non-mixed-case* would be more direct?

Answer (score 2):

## Sum of 3 Vectors

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

### Question

Given 3 vectors `a, b, c`

Find **integer** `(n, m, r)` where `a*n+b*m+c*r = 0` and `n,m,r` are all **not equal to 0**.

your answer group `(n, m, r)` must be the closest valid group to 0, calculate by adding abs value together: `|n|+|m|+|r|`

**You can assume that 3 vectors do not parallel**

### Test case

**work in progress**

### Rules

- no Standard loopholes
- any I/O case allowed, as long as it's clear and mostly understandable.

### Score

- Lowest byte count per language wins!

### Meta

any extra tag?

suggestions?

Rename question?

Comment: this looks like a 3d linear equation solving problem.

Comment: Are the vectors 2-dimensional with integer components?

Comment: @Nitrodon those are 2D vectors currently.

Answer (score 2):

## [Display a number in Toki Pona](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/display-a-number-in-toki-pona)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! Thank you for using the Sandbox first :) I've done some minor edits to add capitalisation and formatting. Tags wise, [integer-partitions] and [natural-language] both apply. [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70847/66833) is a similar challenge, but that uses US coins

Answer (score 2):

## [Distances between keys on a QWERTY keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233618)

Comment: fro kolmogorov i suggest keeping everything in the same unit.

Comment: All jokes aside, this is a well specified challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Unfudge my terminal!

### Intro

Today I fiddled around with termios for a program. The only thing I managed to do so far is fundging my terminal... can you help me out?

### Challenge

Given a terminal input that contains fudged special chars, output the string that should be displayed if the terminal worked correctly. Here's a list of the broken special chars:

```
^B -> Backspace
^J -> (Fwd-) Delete
^W -> Discard
^D -> Cursor left
^C -> Cursor right
^F -> End
^H -> Start
```

### How the special characters work

- Backspace deletes the character behind the cursor and moves it one step back. Has no effect on the start of the string.
- Delete deletes the character in front of the cursor. Has no effect on the end of the string.
- Discard deletes the string typed up to this point.
- Cursor left/right moves the cursor to the left/right by one. Has no effect on the end/start of the string.
- End/Start move the cursor to the end/start of the string.

Undefined special characters are to be removed.

### Input

- Any represetation of a string/list of characters
- Single lines only
- The special characters may be either all capitalized or all not capitalized
- The input will not contain a sequence that will result in a `^` in the output, nor will it contain a single `^` at the end.

### Output

- The unfudged input.
- No leading/trailing whitespace that isn't part of the string.

### Examples

```
abcd^B^B^B --> a

abcd^We^Af^Lgh --> efgh

 gof^D^D^D^Dcode^C^C^Cl --> code golf

ocde gol^H^J^Jco^Ff --> code golf

edgecase^H^D^B^J^F^C^J^B --> dgecas
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins
- Standard loopholes are not allowed
- A submissiom may be a program/function/link/lambda/chain/etc.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Sandbox things

- Is anything unclear?
- Should any special char be added or removed?
- Is there an edge case not covered by the examples?
- Are the rules and I/O restrictions fine or should I change anything?

Answer (score 2):

Comment: Why radiation-hardening? This is the opposite, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

## [Khinchin's constant bad estimate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235843/khinchins-constant-bad-estimate)

Answer (score 2):

## Unicode Calendar Generator

### Rules

Your program will receive a valid date in the format relevant to your language (date object or three int for year, month, day or whatever) and should returns a fancy unicode calendar as such (note that the title is right/left aligned):

Given Y-M-D as 2021-10-13
Then

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ October ░░░░░ 2021 ║
╟──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──╢
║░░│░░│░░│░░│░░│01│02║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║03│04│05│06│07│08│09║
╟──┼──┼──╔══╗──┼──┼──╢
║10│11│12║13║14│15│16║
╟──┼──┼──╚══╝──┼──┼──╢
║17│18│19│20│21│22│23║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║24│25│26│27│28│29│30║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║31│░░│░░│░░│░░│░░│░░║
╚══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╝
```

Given Y-M-D as 2021-11-13
Then

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ November ░░░░ 2021 ║
╟──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──╢
║░░│01│02│03│04│05│06║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╔══╗
║07│08│09│10│11│12║13║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╚══╝
║14│15│16│17│18│19│20║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║21│22│23│24│25│26│27║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║28│29│30│░░│░░│░░│░░║
╚══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╝
```

Given Y-M-D as 2021-06-15
Then

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ June ░░░░░░░░ 2021 ║
╟──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──╢
║░░│░░│01│02│03│04│05║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║06│07│08│09│10│11│12║
╟──┼──╔══╗──┼──┼──┼──╢
║13│14║15║16│17│18│19║
╟──┼──╚══╝──┼──┼──┼──╢
║20│21│22│23│24│25│26║
╟──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──╢
║27│28│29│30│░░│░░│░░║
╚══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╧══╝
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you the shortest bytes of each language will be the winner.

[Inspired by qwerty.dev](https://qwerty.dev/calendar-generator/)

Comment: What does it need the day for? If you want to include the selection of the given day, perhaps you should include that in the challenge post in an example, to keep it self contained.
also is the 00 intentional?

Comment: @thejonymyster fixed. And the 00 was a mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: Are the month/year always to be left/right aligned, like ` May ░░░░░░░░░ 2021 `? What input formats (string, 3 integers, list, built-in date object, ...) are allowed?

Comment: month year should be left/right aligned. For the inputs formats, what would be the most popular?

Comment: I'd recommend allowing any sensible input format (because the challenge is more about producing the calendar than parsing dates). You should explain the alignment rules in the post. Maybe it would be enough to swap one of the examples for a month with a shorter name, but probably better to be explicit.

Comment: What date range is required to support? 1970~2038? Or maybe larger?

Comment: @Dingus lets use any sensible input format

Comment: @tsh I dont have a strong opinion about that.

Comment: tsh's question needs a definite answer because the date range could influence the input method and/or implementation. You should also mention that the Gregorian calendar is used.

Answer (score 2):

Comment: Name suggestion: Wheatian group :)

Answer (score 2):

[Pretty print a grid of polyominoes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236747/107561)

Comment: For challenges which require Unicode, it's generally a good idea to let people count those characters as a single byte each. Aside from that, looks good!

Comment: @emanresuA Thank you very much for your feedback! Is there an easy way to make TIO count like that? Or perhaps as a workaround allow defining the special characters as constants in the header?

Comment: You just generally get people to count, I think. Or you could allow people to use any set of distinct characters instead of the box-drawing characters, or allow both.

Answer (score 2):

[Fast Matrix Multiplicator Evaluator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236841/107969)

Answer (score 2):

## [Will one-cell brainfuck halt?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237514/will-one-cell-brainfuck-halt)

Comment: Do you really want use  `-` for increment while `+` for decrement? Or maybe a typo?

Comment: @tsh Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider all arrays of \$\ell\$ non-negative integers in the range \$0,\dots,m\$.  Consider all such arrays   whose sum is exactly \$s\$.  We can list those in lexicographic order and assign an integer to each one which is simply its rank in the list.

For example, take \$\ell=7, s=5, m=4\$, the list could look like:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4)  rank 1
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3)  rank 2
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2)  rank 3
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1)  rank 4
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4)  rank 5
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3)  rank 6
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)  rank 7
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1)  rank 8
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0)  rank 9
[...]
(3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) rank 449
(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) rank 450
(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) rank 451
(4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) rank 452
(4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) rank 453
(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) rank 454
(4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) rank 455
```

This challenge requires you to produce two pieces of code/functions.

- Given a rank, compute the corresponding array directly. Call this function `unrank()`
- Given an array,  compute its rank. Call this function `rank()`

Your code should run in polynomial time. That is it shouldn't be brute force and more specifically it should take \$O(\ell^a s^b m^c)\$ time for fixed non-negative integers \$a, b, c\$. Any non-brute force method is likely to satisfy this requirement.

## Examples

```
unrank((7, 5, 4), 9) = (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0)
rank((7, 5, 4), (4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)) = 451
unrank((14,10, 8), 100000)  = (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0)
rank((14, 10, 8), (2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)) = 1000000
```

Your score will be the total size for your code

Answer (score 2):

## Lexigolf: Is this number a prime?

Write a program that, given a strictly positive integer **n** as input, determines whether **n** is prime and prints a truthy or falsy value accordingly.

For the purpose of this challenge, an integer is prime if it has exactly two strictly positive divisors. Note that this excludes 1, who is its only strictly positive divisor.

### Goal

Competing programs are compared [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). The program that is lexicographically *less than* all other programs is the winner.

If a program begins with a prefix that may be removed without altering the program's behavior, it is disqualified. This is to discourage adding meaningless whitespace or comments to change the first character (consider    `int main(){}` or `/**/int main(){}`).

For example,

```
abc < def
aa < ba
aaaaaaa < aba
aa < aaaa
Zzz < aaa
012 < AAA
```

### Meta

This is essentially an earlier classic code-golf challenge, [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime), except with a different goal, which I propose is called lexigolf.

I'm not sure whether lexicographic order should entirely be based on UTF-8 (for languages that can be expressed in bytes). It seems to massively favor weird esolangs that rely on characters with small ASCII codes. <strike>There is also a loophole in prefixing the program with noop characters, e.g. placing a arbitrary amount of whitespace before a C program: `int main() {}` >   `int main(int, char**) {}` >     `int main(int argc, char **argv) {}`</strike> (fixed? probably still a loophole somewhere)

Comment: For the scoring favoring weird esolangs that rely on certain characters, the scoring here is typically a per-language comptition, so Java and GolfScript wouldn't be competing. The null byte prefixing is a bit of an issue, so you might want to require that you can't take any number of characters off the left side of the program without making it stop working (so prefixing a null byte wouldn't be allowed unless it actually affected how the program ran). Also, primality testing might not be the best challenge for this idea, since many golfing languages have it as one or two byte built-ins.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena The `<` are to indicate which is lexicographically smaller, not which is winning

Comment: You might want to allow language with SBCSs (custom code pages, instead of UTF-8 or ASCII) like Jelly to use those for the lexicographic order instead, since that would make it more interesting to try to find the lexicographically smallest program in those languages.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms, I've updated the post

Comment: In some languages (for example, Befunge) you could probably detect whether the leading spaces were removed...

Comment: Removing only prefixes isn't enough: I could add a test at the end to check whether that prefix is present. Maybe you should require the code to be [irreducible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/biggest-irreducible-hello-world) instead?

Comment: It seems like this challenge is entirely about finding the lexicographically smallest prefix that can be extended arbitrarily far in a way that removing a prefix of it will be invalid syntax or fail. The prime-finding task doesn't really matter -- any code is equivalent if put after arbitrarily much prefix padding.

Answer (score 2):

## Construct a Heptagon avoiding compass use

A while back I asked you to [construct a pentagon avoiding compass use](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188333/56656).  Now [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) suggested:

> Next time you should ask people to draw a heptagon, which would be slightly more challenging:)

This is of course a joke, because if you didn't already know it is not possible to construct a Heptagon using a ruler and compass ...

... in finite steps.

In this challenge answers will construct equilateral polygon of 7 sides, using a ruler and a compass.

We will begin with some standard ruler and compass operations:

- Draw a line that passes through two non-identical points. (Ruler)
- Draw a circle centered at one point such that another point lies on the circle. (Compass)
- Place a point at an intersection of two non-identical objects (a circle and a line, a line and a line or a circle and a circle)

Normally a construction must be finished after some finite number of operations.  However we will allow you to take any ordinal number of steps.  Meaning you can perform an infinite number of steps and then perform more.

To go with this you are given one more operation:

- Choose converging sequence of already drawn points and place a point at their limit. (limiting)

This operation is only meaningfully useful if you have already performed an infinite number of steps, but is crucial to constructing a heptagon.

### Summary

In this challenge you will start with two arbitrarily placed (but non-equal) points on an infinite plane.  You must then describe some sequence of steps to arrive at a regular Heptagon. Here a regular heptagon simply being 7 points which form the vertices of a heptagon, they do not need to be in any particular position relative to the starting points.

Your score will be the number of compass operations used in the entire proof with lower being better.  Since many answers may end up using an infinite number of compass steps we will break ties by the strict supremum of ordinals representing steps you have used a compass.

For example if two answers both use an infinite number of compass operations, their primary score is \$\infty\$. If one of them uses all of their compasses at finite numbered their secondary score is \$\omega\$, which would beat the other answer if it uses the compass at any time \$\omega\$ and after.

Comment: The theoretical optimal score is likely 2. It is known that a circle and its center (with a couple other known points, because we can't create arbitrary point) plus straightedge operations equals general compass + straightedge in terms of constructibility. It must be possible to construct a sequence of constructible points that converges to a heptagon-related point. The actual challenge is coming up with a constructive solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [How long will my microwave run for?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238134/how-long-will-my-microwave-run-for)

Comment: I'd recommend getting rid of the bonuses, they're pretty strongly discouraged

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I do like the bonus challenge, however I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: You could just turn the bonus challenge into a separate question

Comment: @pxeger I'll make it a seperate question and post it later.

Answer (score 2):

## Code Golf Birthday Cake

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Your task is to print this exact text:

```
     0 2 4 6 8 10
     | | | | | |
    &***********&
    | Code Golf |
   | e---------f |
  | d___________l |
 | o-------------o |
| C_______________G |
 ###Dennis$Dennis###
#####################
```

## Rules

- Trailing or leading newline is allowed
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

---

## Meta

- Any feedback?

Comment: why is it lopsided

Comment: @thejonymyster fixed?

Comment: No, that's more lopsided. You only need one $ between the Dennises, if that helps.

Comment: @thejonymyster fixed?

Comment: Well now the bottom is asymmetric, but also what do the numbers mean?

Comment: @thejonymyster the site is about 9 years old

Comment: Are you sure you want the bottom line have an extra `#` on left side but no such `#` on right side?

Comment: @tsh fixed now?

Comment: can you add more candles?

Answer (score 2):

## [Order of an algebraic number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240111/order-of-an-algebraic-number)

Comment: i find it fascinating although its a bit beyond my knowledge of how to solve it

Comment: Of course this is your challenge, and you can configure it as you wish.  But I'd like to note that, by separating out any answers that employ Built-Ins into a Community Answer, you're effectively reducing this to a "Do X without Y" challenge, where "Y", in this case, is Built-Ins. That takes away the fun of being able to find just the right Built-In (or combination of two or three Built-Ins) to do the job...

Comment: ...fun that you were happy to avail yourself of when you answered each of these two questions with a pair of Built-Ins: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224125/replace-all-items-with-their-counts/224126#224126 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229414/generate-this-number-table/229415#229415

Comment: Sorry I did not spot this problem when the challenge was still in sandbox: `Surd` in Mathematica only gives real roots.

Comment: [Deleted main post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240111/66833)

Comment: @alephalpha I've edited the challenge to include the test cases suggested by you and tsh on the main post. I've also specified that the input will always be real

Comment: @theorist I already know that Mathematica essentially has a builtin for this - it wouldn't surprise me if other math-oriented langs (e.g. Pari/GP) also did. I'm not interested in solutions that off-hand all the work onto a builtin, but banning them isn't something I like doing. Therefore, I go by [this](/a/11218) suggestion to combine trivial builtin answers into a single CW answer. I'm well aware that I've posted builtin-only answers before, but only if the challenge doesn't combine trivial answers into a single CW answer (like I prefer to do)

Comment: There's three problems: (1) For all intents and purposes, the suggestion you are folowing does effectively ban builtins. By requiring any who answer to put builtin solutions into an anonymous community wiki, you are banning them from including builtins in their answers. The practice you've adoped just seems like a way to ban builtins in practice, while saying they're not "technically" banned.   It's a "distinction without a difference."  Thus I think those who adopt this practice shouldn't say "I'm not banning builtins"....

Comment: Instead, I think it's more accurate to say:  "I *am* banning builtins.  But for those who want to post builtins anyways, you can put them into the Community Wiki."  (2) Calling builtin answers "trivial", IMO, unfairly, well, trivializes the knowledge and understanding of a program needed to identify the right builtin for the job. Sure some can be trivial, but I don't think think they should be blanket-labeled as suchl.  E.g., while you may have a different view, I don't think this was trivial: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230836/leave-the-times-out/230861#230861  ...

Comment: The point of the linked example is that `Defer` wasn't designed to accomplish the goal set by the OP, but it nevertheless had that effect anyways. And you needed some understanding of how the language worked to realize it would do that. But it's still a simple one-word builtin. (3) Unless you're programming in machine code, all answers consist of a sequence of builtins. So it really comes down to an arbitrary cutoff of what's the minimum amount of builtins an answer needs to contain.

Comment: To my understanding, the most complex thing here is not find out a minimal polynomial, but instead of how to simplify the input. Especially for testcases like \$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}\cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}\$, or \$\frac{5\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{5}-1}\$.

Answer (score 2):

## Operator precedence is dead

Calculate the result of some math expressions using the following constraints:

- Numbers will be between 0 and 9
- Operators are `+ - / *`
- Expressions will always have the format `Number operator number operator number...`
- Parenthesis have the highest precedence
- The order of reading goes `Left Left Right Right Left Left Right Right etc.`
- Division by 0 never happen

For example:

```
1+3-4*9
1       = 1   ; Start calculating using the left most number
 +    9 = 10  ; Add 9
  3  *  = 30  ; Multiply by 3
   -4   = 26  ; subtract 4
```

Using this method `1+3-4*9 = 26`

### Input / Output

Input:

- string OR list of characters OR list of numbers and characters
- Can be reversed if specified in the answer

Output: a number

### Precision

Floating point errors are OK.

### More examples and test cases:

```
2*9 = 18
```

```
1+3-4*9
1       = 1
 +    9 = 10
  3  *  = 30
   -4   = 26
```

```
8-5*0/9+8/2+3*4
8               = 8
 -            4 = 4
  5          *  = 20
   *        3   = 60
    0      +    = 60
     /    2     = 30
      9  /      = 3.33333...
       +8       = 11.33333...
```

```
Knowing that 1+3-4*9 is 26

8-5*0/9+8/2+(1+3-4*9)*4
8                       = 8
 -                    4 = 4
  5                  *  = 20
   *        (1+3-4*9)   = 520
    0      +            = 520
     /    2             = 260
      9  /              = 28.8888...
       +8               = 36.8888...
```

```
8-2+4*6/2
8         = 8
 -      2 = 6
  2    /  = 3
   +  6   = 9
    4*    = 36
```

```
(1+2*7)*6+3+(2*2+3)

First group:
1+2*7
1
 +  7 = 8
  2*  = 16

Second group:
2*2+3
2
 *  3 = 6
  2+  = 8

(1+2*7)*6+3+(2*2+3)
(1+2*7)             = 16
       *    (2*2+3) = 128
        6  +        = 134
         +3         = 137
```

```
1+(6+(6+1*2)/2)/4
Nested group:
6+1*2
6     = 6
 +  2 = 8
  1*  = 8

Group:
6+(6+1*2)/2
6           = 6
 +        2 = 8
  (6+1*2)/  = 1

Full expression:
1+(6+(6+1*2)/2)/4
1                 = 1
 +              4 = 5
  (6+(6+1*2)/2)/  = 5
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: "Division by 0 should not return a valid number." What do you mean by "a valid number"? I'd suggest just saying answers can assume division by zero will never occur

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @pxeger ! I'm removing errors handling

Answer (score 2):

## Subdivide the Bezier Curve

### Background

A *Bezier curve* is a type of curve that has a lot of applications in all sorts of places, but most commonly, in computer graphics. It has a very simple algorithm and yet can represent a wide variety of shapes with just one common formula. If you've ever used pen tools in drawing software, you're probably already familiar with the general idea behind Bezier curves.

Given an ordered list of control points, we set some parameter \$t\$ in the range \$[0, 1]\$. Then, for each \$t\$, we draw a line between each consecutive pair of control points and select a point that is \$t\$ from the starting point. For example, if we have three control points and \$t\$ is \$\frac13\$:

[image]

The purple point is \$\frac13\$ of the way from the red point to the blue point, and the black point is \$\frac13\$ of the way from the blue point to the green point. You can change the ratio and move the points around [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yc6kh4svqp) to try it out.

Now, we have one fewer point than we initially had control points. Let these be the new control points, and do this again with the same \$t\$:

[image]

([Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uaqwrybz2w)). Now, we finally have a single point, so that is the point we obtain for this value of our parameter \$t\$. The Bezier curve is obtained from all final points for each \$0\leq t\leq 1\$. For more points, we just repeat this for more steps. Here's what a Bezier curve with four control points looks like:

[image]

([Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tj9ooziuv4))

### Challenge

Given a list of control points for a Bezier curve and a positive integer \$n\$, subdivide the Bezier curve into \$n\$ segments and return the points. More precisely, return the output points for \$t=0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\cdots,\frac{n-1}n,1\$.

You may do I/O in any reasonable format; for example, a list of pairs or a pair of x and y coordinates for input, and a pair of numbers for output. Floating point errors are acceptable but your outputs should have an accuracy of at least \$10^{-3}\$ relative or absolute, whichever is larger.

There will be at least one point and \$n\$ will be a positive integer.

### Example

Given input \$\{(0,0),(1,3),(4,2),(5,1)\}\$ and \$3\$ subdivisions:

For \$t=0\$, we just have \$(0,0)\$, and for \$t=1\$ we just have \$(5,1)\$.

For \$t=\frac13\$, we first go \$\frac13\$ of the way from each control point to the next to get \$\{(\frac13,1),(2,\frac83),(\frac{13}3,\frac53)\}\$. Repeating that once more gives us \$\{(\frac89,\frac{14}9),(\frac{25}9,\frac73)\}\$. Finally, if we do it once more, we get the single point \$(\frac{41}{27},\frac{49}{27})\$.

For \$t=\frac23\$, we first get \$\{(\frac23,2),(3,\frac73),(\frac{14}3,\frac43)\}\$, then \$\{(\frac{20}9,\frac{20}9),(\frac{37}9,\frac53)\}\$, and finally, \$(\frac{94}{27},\frac{50}{27})\$. And just for a sanity check, the points are indeed on the curve:

[image]

Note that these points do not evenly subdivide the Bezier curve by arclength. The arclength of a Bezier curve actually cannot be calculated exactly and subdividing like that would have to be done via approximations.

##### [Test case generator](https://tio.run/##bVDdasIwGL1un@IQEL7MKLZDBoJe7gl2JzLatZmZNqlpZe3EZ@@@qGPs5yIkOec7J@ek7tuts/fDoL2roH320hpnG5iqdr7F4w1A1kDHN9BntnBVHBelRkMHuYgjX7ZHbyEUxPTNGUta0Kk7K5z6sxTQzqNT6GEsDjKOPZbYZ1VeZAtouvpNw2ZsS5N0ppDOpMIvIlGYS1a/b82@xJM/lvzyjq3@zj3IOLL/MnNmMmbW5Ck8QVJe4j2HbDz3WtJObuKo9kEgTqOGW4wKLFcQGIEaylhmeZWWUQjBhi4YsigYmW8jizGS8D1RywOaTBDyLedbxvu1yL60lEuskITJC7kmSjBBK3GHLmGXNhxShW@4/4L79FqAOm7XpRyMej4FmIN8mJpyhXydLDahFkcdL5H/6Bd6NRxBDsMn)

<sub>Credit to [Wezl](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59919990) for the original idea.</sub>

Comment: love the interactive parts

Comment: When reading this I didn't expect it to be you having posted it lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Twins' complements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240048/103205)

Answer (score 2):

## [Sides of a polygon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241210/sides-of-a-polygon)

Comment: Will the shape touch itself? Say, like [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fQUFBP0Y/hgtIARkKQAaQjo8HsYAUBMT8/w8A) or [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fAQji47mApL5CTQwXiNKvUQAygHR8jQKQpR8PBTH//wMA) ?

Comment: @tsh  No,it won't.

Comment: By your current examples, [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fXxcCuWoUwKCGSxcK/v8HAA) is a valid shape although it looks very strange.

Comment: @tsh Yeah, I’ll just leave that since allowing those shapes doesn’t car assist any problems or ambiguousities.

Comment: I would like for the valid inputs to be more clearly defined. How many sides does @ths's "very strange" looking shape have?

Answer (score 2):

## [Number of complete rhyme schemes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240624)

Answer (score 2):

## [Is this word in standard order?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241457)

Comment: IMO this would be better as an [tag:array] challenge with arrays of [1,2,3] etc.

Comment: @emanresuA I considered that, but I thought using letters might create some interesting solutions using regular expressions and what-not. Do you think I should allow working over any set (e.g. the natural numbers), not just the alphabet? Or would that be too complex?

Comment: And "some \$x\$"?

Comment: @JonathanFrech What do you mean?

Comment: @pxeger I edited in what I meant; feel free to revert.

Comment: I thought on first looks that this is the same as [Stackable sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144201/20260), but this allows things like `aabcc`, which I think would be a good test case. Perhaps another useful characterization is that if we take the first appearance of each letter, the resulting sequence counts up from `a` without gaps.

Answer (score 2):

## [Solve nonimplication-SAT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241110/solve-nonimplication-sat)

Comment: I don't think there is really one set of "standard [tag:decision-problem] rules" (as there are for [tag:sequence]); you could just say something like "output using any two distinct values representing true and false"

Answer (score 2):

## Domino tilings in an N-dimensional cube [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [dominoes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominoes) [tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

### Challenge

Imagine an N-dimensional cube which has dimensions 2×2×...×2. Given the value of N (a positive integer), calculate the number of ways it can be divided into 2×1×1×...×1 "hyper-domino" pieces (two unit N-dimensional hypercubes glued together).

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples and test cases

For N = 1, the "cube" is a single domino. A single domino can be divided into a single domino in exactly one way, so the answer is 1.

For N = 2, the "cube" is a 2×2 square. It can be divided, or tiled, in two ways:

```
--  ||
--  ||
```

For N = 3, the cube is a 2×2×2 cube. It can be divided into four domino-cubes in nine different ways. One way to count it is to see that, if you pick a unit cube, it can be used by three different domino-cubes (one in each direction), and in all cases the rest forms a small staircase-like shape

```
L1  L2
#   #
##  ##
```

which can be divided into three pieces in three ways (`#` denotes a piece in Z-direction)

```
#   #
--  --

#   #
##  ##

|   |
|#  |#
```

which gives 3×3 = 9.

The corresponding sequence is [A005271](https://oeis.org/A005271).

```
N    Answer
-----------
1    1
2    2
3    9
4    272
5    589185
6    16332454526976
7    391689748492473664721077609089
```

Answer (score 2):

[Is it a perfect word?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241080/is-it-a-perfect-word)

Comment: @mathcat "The word may always be assumed to be lowercase."

Answer (score 2):

## [Is this continuous terrain?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241136/is-this-continuous-terrain#241136)

Comment: [Suggested Testcase]([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fP0ZBQUGfS0EhRkFfgQvEVlD4/x8A "PHP – Try It Online"))

Comment: I am unsure if you should allow both `~` and `-`. Can one even freely mix them?

Comment: @JonathanFrech as in you can choose to take input with overlines replaced with one of them

Comment: question name idea: "is this continuous terrain?" I have a feeling there is a dupe of this.

Comment: @Razetime Good idea!

Answer (score 2):

## Number of arrangements of half a Rubik's cube

From a corner-on view of a Rubik's cube calculate the number of arrangements of *stickers* that are out of view.

Your input will provide the state of a Rubik's cube when viewed like the below image:

[image]

This input will be an array, in any defined order†, grouping†, and nesting† that you choose, containing the colours‡ of the \$27\$‡ *stickers* (A.K.A. *facelets* or *tiles*) on three sides of a 3x3 Rubik's cube that join at one corner, like you can see above.

The input may be assumed to be that of a solvable state where only face turns can return the cube to having six sides with a single colour on each (if it isn't then your code may do anything, short of summoning Cthulhu).

† The input may be a flat list of colour-labels or you may specify that these labels will already be grouped in any way you wish (it may be a ragged, nested list for example), but the content thereof should only consist of the *sticker* colour-labels.

‡ Since the centres of the cube are actually fixed relative to each other, and hence the hidden centres' colours are known, you may choose to leave any or all of the central *stickers* out of the expected input (it could be as short as \$24\$ *sticker* colour-labels) while using a labeling that identifes the colours as the top-centre, left-centre, right-centre, and their three opposite colours. For the record, the standard colour theme, as in the image above, has orange opposite red, white opposite yellow, and green opposite blue (hence orange is the hidden centre sticker on the bottom etc.).

You should output the number of possible arrangements of *sticker* colours of the \$27\$ *stickers* which are **not** in the input (i.e. those *stickers* which are out of view). Note that swapping two of those *stickers* of the same colour is considered to be the same arrangement.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)[rubiks-cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)

---

#### Sandbox questions

1. Does this need test cases? (I'm not even 100% sure what the output should be if the input looked like a solved cube from that perspective although I may be able to work it out without writing a program it's certainly more than one - e.g. `U' L R2 D' M D2 M' D' L' R2 U` or  `R2 U R2 F2 R2 U2 F2 R2 F2 U R2`)
2. Is the spec clear?

Comment: You should probably make it more explicit that the center colors of the opposite faces are known.  (Also, I'm fairly sure that a "solved cube" input would have an output of 192, but that's just me doing quick math in my head, so I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

## Implement an argwhere function [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241357/implement-an-argwhere-function)

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing "no", but are langs without function definition allowed to participate?

Comment: @thejonymyster I'm not too interested in making restrictions. If your language can accept code as input and run it to make decisions, I'd say that's good enough. But as with all `functional-programming` questions, some languages will inevitably be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

## BCD to binary, with bitwise

[atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

---

In this challenge, you'll convert an 8-digit BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) number to a 32 bit (unsigned) integer in the fewest instructions possible, with only bitwise instructions available.

**Task:**

You'll be given a single positive integer as input, from `00000000` to `999999999`. It will be represented using BCD, as a 4-byte unsigned integer, with each nibble being a decimal digit from `0000` (0) to `1010` (10). More significant nibbles will correspond to more significant digits of the decimal number.

Your output should be that same number, as an ordinary 32-bit integer.

**Instructions:**

This is atomic code golf, so you can only use the following instructions, the number of which is used for scoring:

```
and [r], [r|I]      Bitwise AND
or  [r], [r|I]      Bitwise OR
xor [r], [r|I]      Bitwise XOR

not [r]             Bitwise NOT

shr [r], [r|I]      Shift right (zero fill)
shl [r], [r|I]      Shift left

mov [r], [r|I]      Copy
```

All instructions will write their output to the first register listed, and for the second argument `[r|I]` indicates either a register or an immediate (any 32-bit constant) can be provided.

You have four registers to work with, all of which hold a single 4 byte unsigned integer: `ra`, `rb`, `rc`, and `rd`. Any instruction using only registers costs 1 byte, and any with an immediate cost a total of 4 (this isn't technically possible, since the immediates are 4 bytes on their own, but I don't want to make them too costly).

Input will be provided in `ra`, and the contents of `ra` when your program is finished will be used as output. All other registers will be initialized to `0`.

**Instructions Mk. 2:**

This is atomic code golf, so you can only use the following instructions, the number of which is used for scoring:

```
and [r], [r|I]      Bitwise AND
or  [r], [r|I]      Bitwise OR
xor [r], [r|I]      Bitwise XOR

not [r]             Bitwise NOT

shr [r], [r|I]      Shift right (zero fill)
shl [r], [r|I]      Shift left

mov [r], [r|I]      Copy

goto [r|I]          Go to an instruction (`0` is the start of the program)
goif [r] [r|I]      Go to an instruction, if `r` is not all `0`s
```

All instructions (aside from `goto` and `goif`) will write their output to the first register listed, and for the second argument `[r|I]` indicates either a register or an immediate (any 32-bit constant) can be provided.

You have 8 registers to work with, all of which hold a single 4 byte unsigned integer: `ra`, `rb`, `rc`, `rd`, `rk`, `rn`, `rp`, and `rs`. Any instruction using only registers costs 1 score, and any with an immediate cost a total of 2.

Input will be provided in `ra`, and the contents of `ra` when your program is finished will be used as output. All other registers will be initialized to `0`.

**Other:**

I don't actually know if this is an interesting challenge, or if more registers will be needed, or if there's already a well known solution. I'd try it myself but it's kinda late here so I'm too tired to, and if I don't post this now I'll forget about it lol

Comment: Maybe just give infinite amount of registers and don't call them "byte" but "score"?

Answer (score 2):

## [Compress and decompress](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241259/compress-and-decompress?noredirect=1#comment544064_241259)

Comment: [tag:self-referential] might be better than [tag:quine]. But are you assuming normal quine rules? Are programs allowed to introspect their own source code?

Comment: This challenge is fairly similar to [Encode a Lenguage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229994), but I think it's sufficiently open-ended that it's different in an interesting way.

Comment: Personally I think this would be more interesting if you were allowed to read your source code, because otherwise it becomes too much of a [quine variant](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595) where most of the code is taken up by encoding the program's source code, and not the interesting task (which is the compression). (Sorry, I probably should have given you this opinion before I asked you to decide whether quine rules applied)

Comment: @pxeger I added the quine rules specifically to discourage solutions where you just swap your programs source code and a single input. The other (more interesting imo.) approach is to actually do compression and then make your source code compressible.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mat Printing Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241219)

Comment: er wats default I/O @adam

Comment: im sorry i dont understand @adam could u explain the defualt IO (i alr read the link doesnt rly help) or edit my post thx

Comment: like this? i changed it

Comment: Yeah, this looks great. Maybe put in the tags you plan on using.

Comment: @adam pls edit the tags if its wrong thx

Answer (score 2):

## [Crack the Caesar cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241532/66833)

Comment: Can we not have to deal with capitalisation?

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 2):

## Prime Number Fibonacci

In this challenge, you will make a program that calculates the Fibonacci sequence with a twist. Instead of it starting with 0 and 1, it starts with the nth prime number determined by input by the user. The second number is the nth+1 prime number. The sequence should also stop after nth number iterations.

#### Walkthrough:

1. Get a number from the input. We will call it `n`
2. Calculate the `n` prime number and `n+1` prime number
3. Make a function that adds these numbers and calls itself with the result.
4. Make the function stop once prime number with index `n` numbers are output

#### Examples:

```
input:2
output:
8
13
21
34
55

input:10
output:
60
91
151
242
393
635
1028
1663
2691
4354
7045
11399
18444
29843
48287
78130
126417
204547
330964
535511
866475
1401986
2268461
3670447
5938908
9609355
15548263
25157618
40705881
65863499
106569380

input:5
output:
24
37
61
98
159
257
416
673
1089
1762
2851
4613
7464
```

By the way, here is the JavaScript code I used for this example:

```
var primeNumber1 = prime(num);
var primeNumber2 = prime(num+1);
fib(primeNumber1,primeNumber2,0,primeNumber1);
}
function fib(num1,num2,iterations,max){
console.log(num1+num2);
if(iterations == max+1){
return;
}
fib(num2,num1+num2,iterations+1,max);
}
function prime(number){
var numPrime = 0;
for(var i = 0; i > -1; i++){
if(isPrime(i)){
numPrime++;
if(numPrime == number){
return i;
}
}
}
}
function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}
```

Comment: I would define the task more clearly. Something along the lines of (if I understood correctly) "Let \$(p_k)_{k\geq 1}\$ denote the ordered sequence of all prime numbers. Given a natural number \$n\geq 1\$, output \$(a_1,\dots,a_{p_n+p_{n+1}})\$ where \$a_{-1}:=p_n\$, \$a_0:=p_{n+1}\$ and \$a_k:=a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}\$ for \$k\geq 1\$."

Comment: @JonathanFrech I have no idea what those symbols mean except for greater than and I know := is used in statically typed programming language to infer the type of a variable. Could you explain what the math string means and how it would clarify my question?

Comment: When you say "the nth prime number", is for you 2 the prime number with index \$0\$ or \$1\$? I guess the latter, so \$p_1=2\$. Then I understand your task to be printing \$p_n\$ integers which are defined as follows: the first number to be printed is \$a_1=p_n+p_{n+1}\$, the second is \$a_2=p_{n+1}+a_1\$, the third \$a_3=a_1+a_2\$ and so on up to \$a_{p_n+p_{n+1}}\$. I found it hard to read into your explanation and would like a more clear definition of the task -- be it with formulae or word descriptions.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I have to infer from your example that the 2nd prime number is 3 and "Make a function that adds these numbers and calls itself with the result." requires thinking of Fibonacci to properly interpret.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex ordinals

Inspired by [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1313/), your job is to write an extremely meta regex.

Specifically, the depth of a regex is an [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) defined as follows:

1. `regex golf` has depth 0.
2. `meta-x` has depth 1 greater than the depth of `x`.
3. The depth of `<regex>` is the supremum of the depths of everything `<regex>` matches.

Of course, it's possible for a string not to have a depth. For example, `/.*/` matches itself, so its depth would have to be greater than its depth, which is impossible.

Your challenge is to write a regex with depth \$\omega^2\$.

And this is code golf, so the shortest regex wins.

### Examples of regex ordinals

- `meta-regex golf` is depth 1.
- `meta-meta-regex golf` is depth 2.
- `/(meta-)*regex golf/` is depth \$\omega\$.
- `/(meta-)*\/(meta-)\*regex golf\//` is depth \$\omega 2\$.

Comment: Similar: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205274/program-ordinals-and-omega-squared/. Should I link it?

Answer (score 2):

## [Animate finding the middle (hypercube edition)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241905/animate-finding-the-middle-hypercube-edition)

Comment: "All dimensions are the same" should probably be worded more like; "All dimensions are the same length".

Comment: @Adám Added testcase

Comment: @emanresuA The last text case contradicts "until it has less than 3 elements left".

Comment: @Adám You asked for that testcase. But if it's invalid, I'll remove it.

Comment: @emanresuA It isn't invalid per se, but your spec is odd. Why not say "until the length of each dimension is less than 3"?

Answer (score 2):

## [Move to Right and left](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241474/66833)

Comment: why are there X crossings? wouldn't they just combine right there?

Comment: @thejonymyster this is cross.

Answer (score 2):

## [Trap the hero in a maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241749/trap-the-hero-in-a-maze)

Answer (score 2):

## Von Neumann Probe Battle ([king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill))

---

This is just an idea for now, placing it here as a draft and to collect feedback.

Basically, your goal would be to design a set of machines, including factories and spacecraft, which start on earth and spread outward into the universe. You'd be able to design these machines. Not just their code, but the parts that make them up.

For example, you could start on earth with a single factory, which would make a swarm of mining bots. These would bring ore to the surface, and the factory would switch to making spacecraft. Once the spacecraft are built, the factory could assemble all of the parts needed to make an identical factory, load them onto the spacecraft, and send them to the moon. Then, both factories would start the process over.

The ultimate goal would be to build "stamps", which cost a small amount of iron, and then vanish from existence. These are used for scoring.

This challenge might not be very practical, due to the issues involved in simulating a detailed and exponentially increasing swarm of robots in a vast universe.

Comment: stamps? you mean paperclips

Comment: @GingerIndustries Maybe :p

Answer (score 2):

## Pretty print my arrays

I [like](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241650/sort-every-dimension) [to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233030/build-me-a-room) [pretty print](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236884/remove-submatrices) multidimensional arrays, like this:

```
[ [ [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6] ],
  [ [7, 8, 9],
    [6, 4, 2] ] ]
```

But it's a pain to do by hand and it'd be nice to have a program that does this for me. Your challenge is to create a program that does this for me, taking a multidimensional array containing only numbers and prettyprinting it.

Specifically, an array of depth 1 is printed joined by `,`  with `[` prepended and `]` appended:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

An array of depth \$n+1\$, which contains at least one array of depth \$n\$, has its subarrays prettyprinted, joined by newlines and indented by two spaces. All but the last subarray have a comma appended, the last has  `]` appended, and the first has its first line indented with `[`  instead of two spaces:

[image]

Here's a reference implementation:

```js
function recursivePrettyPrint(array){
  if(array.every(x => typeof x == "number")){
    return `[${array.join(', ')}]`;
  } else {
    return array.map((item, index) => {
      let result = recursivePrettyPrint(item) + ',';
      result = result.split`\n`;
      if(index == 0){
        result[0] = '[ ' + result[0];
      } else {
        result[0] = '  ' + result[0];
      }
      for(let i = 1; i < result.length; i++){
        result[i] = '  ' + result[i]
      }
      return result.join('\n');
    }).join('\n').slice(0,-1) + ' ]';
  }
}

function change(){
  let array = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('input').value);
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerText = recursivePrettyPrint(array);
}
```

```html
<textarea id=input></textarea>

<button id=run onclick=change()>Pretty Print</button>

<pre id=output></pre>
```

Numbers may be multiple digits. The input will always be orthogonal/rectangular, and you may take its dimensions as well.

### Testcases

````
[[892, 759], [962, 251]] ->
[ [892, 759],
  [962, 251] ]

[118, 922, 619] ->
[118, 922, 619]

[[966, 639, 616, 255], [622, 483, 87, 241], [453, 870, 728, 725], [163, 936, 48, 967], [261, 833, 87, 200]] -> 
[ [966, 639, 616, 255],
  [622, 483, 87, 241],
  [453, 870, 728, 725],
  [163, 936, 48, 967],
  [261, 833, 87, 200] ]

[[[[[912, 547], [366, 754]], [[723, 536], [779, 238]]], [[[559, 392], [602, 709]], [[692, 915], [412, 302]]]], [[[[3, 504], [936, 83]], [[352, 442], [425, 375]]], [[[380, 440], [793, 762]], [[850, 321], [780, 457]]]]] ->
[ [ [ [ [912, 547],
        [366, 754] ],
      [ [723, 536],
        [779, 238] ] ],
    [ [ [559, 392],
        [602, 709] ],
      [ [692, 915],
        [412, 302] ] ] ],
  [ [ [ [3, 504],
        [936, 83] ],
      [ [352, 442],
        [425, 375] ] ],
    [ [ [380, 440],
        [793, 762] ],
      [ [850, 321],
        [780, 457] ] ] ] ]

[[[128, 910, 664, 658], [172, 238, 564, 492], [325, 384, 566, 90]], [[876, 819, 764, 105], [583, 528, 731, 839], [480, 126, 692, 875]], [[215, 84, 268, 504], [400, 674, 997, 526], [799, 692, 193, 296]], [[943, 185, 567, 188], [118, 200, 879, 409], [116, 493, 62, 343]]] -> 
[ [ [128, 910, 664, 658],
    [172, 238, 564, 492],
    [325, 384, 566, 90] ],
  [ [876, 819, 764, 105],
    [583, 528, 731, 839],
    [480, 126, 692, 875] ],
  [ [215, 84, 268, 504],
    [400, 674, 997, 526],
    [799, 692, 193, 296] ],
  [ [943, 185, 567, 188],
    [118, 200, 879, 409],
    [116, 493, 62, 343] ] ]
```
````

Comment: "Numbers may be multiple digits" but you should state that numbers will be the only atomic data to occur.

Comment: Fine challenge, but I hate this way of printing arrays :P

Comment: May I input the array as a string? If so, what formatting may I assume for the input array? For example, will there always be a space after each comma?

Answer (score 2):

## Ragged list addition

Let's define the operator \$+\$ as follows, using wrapping list indexing:

\$
a+b=\begin{cases}
a+b,\space\text{if }a\text{ and }b\text{ are integers (regular integer addition)}\\
[a+b[0], a+b[1], ...,a+b[len(b)-1]],\text{if }a\text{ is an integer and }b\text{ is a list}\\
[a[0]+b,a[1]+b,...,a[len(a)-1]+b],\text{if }b\text{ is a list and }\text{ is an integer}\\
[a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2],...,\\a[\max(len(a),len(b))-1]+b[\max(len(a),len(b))-1]],\text{if }a\text{ and }b\text{ are lists}
\end{cases}
\$

That is huge wall of text, so let's look at an example: We want to add the arrays \$[1,2,[5,6,7]]\$ and \$[[1],2,3,10,0,[3,0],1]\$ together

Let's start

\$[1,2,[5,6,7]]+[[1],2,3,10,0,[3,0],1]\$

We are adding two arrays, so we add element by element, looping if neccesary:

\$[1+[1],2+2,[5,6,7]+3,1+10,2+0,[5,6,7]+[3,0],1+1]\$

Now, let's get all the additions that don't involve lists out of the way

\$[1+[1],4,[5,6,7]+3,11,2,[5,6,7]+[3,0],2]\$

Next, lets look at \$1+[1]\$ and \$[5,6,7]+3\$. Here we add an integer to an array, so we just distribute the addition like so:

\$[[1+1],4,[5+3,6+3,7+3],11,2,[5,6,7]+[3,0],2]\$

\$[[2],4,[8,9,10],11,2,[5,6,7]+[3,0],2]\$

Now we have \$[5,6,7]+[3,0]\$ left. Again, we interleave the arrays, looping if necessary:

\$[[2],4,[8,9,10],11,2,[5+3,6+0,7+3],2]\$

\$[[2],4,[8,9,10],11,2,[8,6,10],2]\$

Now there are no \$+\$ signs left. Thus \$[1,2,[5,6,7]]+[[1],2,3,10,0,[3,0],1]=[[2],4,[8,9,10],11,2,[8,6,10],2]\$

Note that ragged list addition is not commutative. So \$a+b\$ is not necessarily the same as \$b+a\$.

Your code takes two ragged lists and returns their sum. Shortest code wins.

Answer (score 2):

## Slice the source code - [Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242616/slice-the-source-code-cops/) and [Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242618/slice-the-source-code-robbers/)

Comment: Try to clarify the robbers challenge and add a example

Comment: Challenges should be self contained: i.e. copy the relevant info from the link onto the question

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Added a example.

Comment: not bad although i never understand cops and robbers challenge +1

Comment: Really love it. Can't wait for it to be posted!

Comment: @DLosc done....

Comment: It would also be good to add examples for negative indices and a negative step value. If people haven't seen Python-style slicing before, they might be very confused about why `[::-1]` is "reverse the code."

Answer (score 2):

## Can I wall glitch to there?

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242581/can-i-wall-glitch-to-there)

Answer (score 2):

## Play a chess-like game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Your task is to build a program that plays chess.  However, it doesn't know how the pieces move before the game begins.  In fact, each time it sits down at the board the pieces are different!

### The game

This game is played on a 6x6 board, looking roughly like:

```
123451
pppppp
......
......
pppppp
123451
```

Each game has a time control of 1+1 (1 minute, plus 1 second per move).  One piece (of 2345) is selected to be the king, and the game ends when any of the following occur:

- A king is captured (a win for the capturing player)
- 50 moves pass without a piece being captured or a pawn moving (a draw)
- One player runs out of time or attempts an invalid move. (a loss for that player)

### The pieces

##### Pawns

Each player has 6 pawns.  Pawns have at least one possible capturing move and at least one non-capturing move that moves it forward.  If a pawn moves into a space on the last rank, it may promote into any non-king piece.  I've listed white's moves; blacks are mirrored.  Pawns may have any or all of the following:

```
Capturing or non-capturing

.x.
... x.x .x. ...
.p. .p. .p. xpx

Capturing only

.p. .p.
x.x .x.

Example:
In a game, pawns may be able to move to

...
.x.
xpx

And capture pieces in

x.x
.p.
xxx
```

##### Major Pieces

The major pieces are more varied, but all of their moves are symmetric.  If a major piece can move to a space, it can also capture on that space.  Possible moves include (not necessarily exhaustive):

```
.x. x.x
xPx .P.
.x. x.x

These moves may or may not include the ability to jump over pieces in between:

.x.x. x.x.x
x...x .....
..P.. x.P.x
x...x .....
.x.x. x.x.x

These moves extend across the whole board:

.x... x.x.. P....
xPxxx .P... ..x..
.x... x.x.. .x..x
.x... ...x. .....
.x... ....x ..x..
```

Each piece will have at least one of these (or others - no guarantees will be made that other movesets will not be included).  A piece can have any number of these sets of moves.  The two "1"s will have the same moves.

### The controller

I haven't built this; I want to gauge interest first.

A potential spec for the controller (have to work out how it communicates):

```
// Return a list of possible moves in that game state
// If piece is passed (a 2-element array - [x,y]) then only moves which that piece can make are returned
getMoves(board, player, piece = null) => board[]

// Returns the number of milliseconds that player has remaining on their clock.
getTime(player) => float

// Move the piece at origin to destination
makeMove(origin, destination, promotion = null) => void
```

### The tournament

There will be a round-robin tournament played, with as many rounds as possible.  Each game will have its pieces randomized at the start, then the bots will play a game as white and a game as black (using the same pieces).

## Sandbox

- Does this sound like an interesting challenge (would it be more than just "fork stockfish")?
- Would it be alright to restrict this to javascript?

Comment: If you restrict it to a single language, C++ doesn't seem like a very good choice. This KotH will already probably have a high barrier of entry, and a lot of people here probably won't know C++ well enough to bother trying to compete at all.

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani Fair point.  Performance is a non-negligible factor here, so it's likely that if I don't restrict it to a single language, python or similar may not be able to compete.  Restricting it to a single language would alleviate that risk.  Python would be my next choice - and I might have to loosen the time control for that.

Comment: Do you know JS? If so, that's a good middle-ground between C++ and Python in terms of performance and accessiblity, and it has the advantage of being able to port it to the browser so people can test bots more easily.

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani Interesting.  I thought JS was considerably worse than python!  Yeah, could do that, then.

Answer (score 2):

### Round it up Nicely

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

When I work out, I often don't have a good plan for how many times to repeat an exercise, but in the interest of pushing myself I always keep going until I've done a "nice" number. Multiples of 5 are ideal, but multiples of 4 are acceptable too--unless they're 1 less than a multiple of 5, in which case I may as well do one more, or they're 1 more than a multiple of 5, in which case why didn't I already stop?

#### The challenge

Given an integer \$n\$ and a descending, pairwise coprime list of integers \$k_1, k_2, ..., k_m\$, output the least integer \$x \geq n\$ which is a multiple of some \$k_i\$ but is not 1 more or less than any multiple of any \$k_j\$ with \$j<i\$.

#### Test cases

```
n    k[1]...k[m]                        result
1    [5, 4]                             5
15   [5, 4]                             15
12   [5, 4]                             12
16   [5, 4]                             20
7    [5, 4]                             8
996  [5, 4]                             1000
1    [11, 7]                            7
15   [11, 7]                            22
133  [11, 7]                            140
1    [5, 3, 2]                          3
6    [5, 3, 2]                          10
6    [5, 3]                             10
11   [5, 3, 2]                          12
1    [100, 49, 9]                       9
```

### Sandbox

- Would it be more interesting without the descending/coprime guarantees?
- Test cases are a WIP, but any additional suggestions?
- Better title?
- [How] should I note that the 1-above exclusion only matters if it would exclude the input itself? Should the task not be "rounding up" to make it more relevant?

Comment: the "dynamic goal" thing made me think it was going to be a challenge about determining how much excersize youd be doing in a given section, the sequence thing seems way out of left field and the requirements to be a workout number arbitrary, even in relation to the lore

Comment: Could you please use words to describe the challenge? I do read quantifiers, but I suspect not all golfers do.

Answer (score 2):

[Retaining Water](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242453/retaining-water)

Comment: I like this challenge but I think the string input is unnecessary.  A 2D list of ints would be a better format in my opinion.

Comment: can i say "- You are allowed to take in the input as 2D list of integers
" @WheatWizard?

Comment: I would just have the input be a 2D list of integers.  I can hardly imagine it being more convenient to take the current format.

Comment: do i manually change the entire input, or just write The input is in the form of a 2D list of integers

Comment: @WheatWizard is my challenge now ok?

Answer (score 2):

## [All sequences as substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242713/all-sequences-as-substrings)

Answer (score 2):

## [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242780/107561)

Answer (score 2):

[Simulating Bombs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242875/simulating-bombs)

Answer (score 2):

## Make me a k-NN classifier

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [machine-learning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) *The "machine-learning" tag will be created*

---

The [k Nearest Neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (k-NN) classifier is a simple machine learning classifier. Although k-NN also works for regression tasks, we will be focusing on classification tasks for this challenge.

The classifier can be customized in a number of different ways. For this challenge, the following can be customized:

- `k` itself;
- the distance metric; and
- the aggregation function.

### Main idea

As you can probably tell by its name, k-NN works using the concept of *neighbors*. First, we "train" classifiers by giving it (preferably a lot of) training data.

A training data point consists of two parts: its "features" and its target value. For instance, if predicting car brand, features might be maximum speed, size etc, and the target variable would be brand. We can also specify `k`, a distance metric, and/or an aggregation function, or let the classifier fine-tune these hyperparameters itself. For this challenge, the above hyperparameters will be given directly to the classifier.

When we give the classifier a list of features to be assigned a predicted target value, it takes the `k` train points closest to the test point, measured by distance metric via features, and runs their target values through its aggregation function to obtain its prediction.

The hyperparameters are explained below:

### `k`

`k` is the neighbor count. If `k` is 5, for instance, the classifier will consider 5 neighbors when predicting.

### Distance metric

The distance metric measures how far two data points are from each other, measured by their features. A standard distance metric is Euclidean distance, but many others can be used, such as the Manhattan distance.

### Aggregation function

Once the classifier has found the `k` nearest neighbors, it calls its aggregation function using the target values of these neighbors. A standard aggregation function for classification is majority vote, but many others can be used.

### Challenge

The following are to be taken as input:

- a list of train data points where each data point consists of:

  - a list of numbers, where the lengths of these lists are the same for all training data points; and
  - a target value;
- `k`;
- a distance metric which takes two data points' features and outputs a positive number; and
- an aggregation function which takes `k` data points' target values and outputs a value that is one of the target values contained within the training data (this means that you can't just output some arbitrary number; it must be a target value for at least one of the train data points);

You may also take in the following:

- a list of features of the same length as every list of features within the training data.

Output:

- if an additional list of features was given, the prediction, found using the procedure described above, for that list of features;
- if no such list was given, a function that takes in a list of features as described above and outputs the prediction for that list of features.

Input is flexible so long as it is within reason.

The distance metric and aggregation function are black-box functions.

This challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code, measured in bytes, wins.

### Test case

Given in python.

```py
k = 5
distance = lambda a, b: sum((b[i] - a[i]) ** 2 for i in range(5)) # Euclidean distance
aggregation = lambda a, b, c, d, e: max([a, b, c, d, e], key=lambda i: [a, b, c, d, e].count(i)) # output the one with the most occurrences
train = [
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0],
 [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1],
 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 1],
 [[1, 4, 5, 6, 7], 0],
 [[1, 8, 9, 9, 9], 0],
 [[9, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1],
 [[2, 3, 4, 1, 1], 1]
]

classifier_func = knn_classifier(train, k, distance, aggregation) # function output

print(classifier_func([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])) # outputs 1
```

---

Do we have any feedback? Duplicate? Clarification needed? Wrong terminology? Wrong test case?

Comment: Maybe you should include algorithm the knn classifier used. And how should answers handle random numbers if any randomness is involved in the algorithm.

Comment: @tsh The functions given as input are black-box functions. And I'm not sure what you mean by "including the algorithm the knn classifier used". You mean add the code for the classifier?

Answer (score 2):

## [Golf the prime numbers in Shue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242897/golf-the-prime-numbers-in-shue)

Comment: how are you this smart to create such a challenge?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the language. What does `b!c` mean? What is `=|` (without anything before it on a line)?

Comment: @ophact so the only characters with special meaning are `=`, `\ ` and the newline. `b!c` is just a string like any other. I could have used `T` instead of `!`, it's just an arbitrary character that is used as a separator. `=|` means that you can replace the empty string with `|`, meaning that for example, if we had the string `Hello`, we could transform it to `H|ello` or `|Hello|` or `|H|e|l|l||||||||||o|` and so on.

Comment: @l4m2 If you mean a character or string that matches the beginning of the string, the answer is no.

Comment: Output mean it need whole match?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, otherwise it wouldn't be turing complete.

Comment: Why not `ab` => `a|b` => `|` => `L|`  => `no`?

Comment: but `ab` match `"a"*x+"b"*x`

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, that's right, I'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

[Chess Board Analyzer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242986/chess-board-analyzer)

Comment: I really like this

Answer (score 2):

## Disassemble tables

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243134/disassemble-tables).

Comment: awesome puzzle ophact! at the moment, i do not have any feedback other than well done!

Comment: #4 seems to have an extra pair of legs

Comment: @emanresuA thanks, will edit now

Answer (score 2):

## Random Point from a 2D Donut Distribution

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243774/random-point-from-a-2d-donut-distribution).

Comment: I don't think the current definition of the distribution is unambiguous?  Is this intentional?  Is this [tag:open-ended-function] or did you mean to specify an exact distribution?

Comment: @Jitse Different distributions can have the same standard deviation. Perhaps you forgot to specify that the radius of the points should have a normal distribution?

Comment: @AnttiP You're absolutely right, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: So what we need is just generate \$ R \sim {\mathcal {N}}(r ,s^2) \$, \$ \theta \sim U[0, 2\pi]\$. And convert to Cartesian coordinate system \$(R\cos \theta, R\sin \theta)\$?

Comment: @tsh $$ R \sim {\mathcal {N}}(r ,s) $$, but yes

Answer (score 2):

## [Smallest maximal rectangle in a skyline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242982/smallest-maximal-rectangle-in-a-skyline)

Comment: u can say that this is like version 2 of the previous challenge u posted similar to this

Answer (score 2):

## [Wiggle the tower](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243078/wiggle-the-tower)

Answer (score 2):

## Golf the colors of a rug

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

### Background

The challenge is based on this rug:

[image: Rug]

Its colors seem very regular, but the pattern isn't obvious. However, it becomes visible when we move vertical stripes of the rug up and down:

[image: Rug strips]

All stripes are colored in the same way, but each stripe is offset by some height, except for a few irregularities. Also, the stripes have different widths.

First, we need to list all colors:

```
0: blue-ish white
1: lighter blue
2: darker blue
3: darkest blue
4: green-ish white (the color between the middle orange rows)
5: middle green
6: dark green
7: orange
8: light red
9: dark red
```

Now, we can lay a grid of cells of equal color over this image. I found that using a cell size of 73.5x129 pixels seems to be a good compromise between precision and compactness. This results in a 42x32 grid, which looks like this when overlayed over the rug:

[image: Rug grid]

Correcting for some perspective errors, we now can approximate the colors of this rug like this:

[image: Rug simplified]

The color scheme shared by all stripes consists, from top to bottom, of these 42 colors: `[3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]`. (This already contains the information that some rows have different heights, by having multiple entries of the same color in a row.)

There are 18 stripes with widthes `[2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3]`.
Their vertical offsets are `[3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 9, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5]`, which means the first stripe starts at the color at index 3 in the common scheme, the second stripe at index 4 and so on. Starting from the respective start index, the next 32 colors are used; remaining colors (if any) are unused.

There are some irregularities in the rug. I didn't find a better way of expressing them except for listing their X and Y coordinates in the grid together with their colors:

```
X     [8,  9, 10, 19, 19, 12,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  2,  3,  4,  2,  3,  4,  5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 34]
Y     [18, 18, 18, 23, 24, 27, 31, 31, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31]
Color [5,  5,  5,  0,  0,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  8,  8,  9]
```

They are included in this challenge to better reflect the rug and to increase difficulty a bit.

### Challenge

Output this 42x32 grid of numbers from 0-9, each corresponding to the color of one cell of the rug:

```
333333333332322223302222221222332233333222
332223332223333332221111111122332233322222
222222222223233332221111113100220022222000
220002220002322220013333331322222222200222
002220002222322222211111111122002200022222
222222222220200002231111115111221122222111
221112221112222221115555555511221122211111
111111111112022221115555556533113311111333
113331113331211113356666665611111111133111
331113331111211111155555555511331133311111
111111111113133331165555556555115511111555
115551115551111115556666666655115511155555
555555555551311115556666667666556655555666
556665556665155556667777776755555555566555
665556665555155555566666666655665566655555
555555555556566665576666667666556655555666
556665556665555556667777777766556655566666
666666666665655556667777774777667766666777
667776665556566667774444447466666666677666
776667776666566666677777777766776677766666
666666666667677776647777778777667766666777
667776667776666667778888888877667766677777
777777777776766667778888887844774477777444
774447774447677774407777778777777777744777
447774447777677777708888888877447744477777
777777777774744447778888889888778877777888
778887778887777778889999999988778877788888
888888888887877778889999998977887788888777
887778887778788887798888889888888888877888
779997778888788888899999999988778877788888
889998888887877778889999999999889988888999
998889889998899998899999999999889998899999
```

### Rules

- The program should not take input.
- Formatting doesn't matter.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

### Sandbox Questions

- Why doesn't the box with irregularities align?
- Would the challenge be more fun with or without having to include irregularities? I guess allowing both variants is not a good idea because solutions aren't comparable anymore.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/19231#19231

Comment: Whoops, I missed that... I adjusted the challenge to include a description of the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

## Flipping Burnt Pancakes, but Optimally!

This is based on the [Burnt Pancake problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting#The_burnt_pancake_problem).

In the burnt pancake problem, each “pancake” has a burnt side. You must sort these pancakes in order with the burnt side down. You may only use one tool, your spatula, which can flip the pancakes from the top of the pancake stack to where you inserted the spatula.

Flipping pancakes that have the burnt side down results in those pancakes being in reverse order and having the burnt side up, and vice versa.

For a given pancake stack, return the minimal number of flips needed to be made burnt pancake sorting.

The output must show every step of the optimal flipping process, with the position of the spatula being represented by a pipe character, and u or b after every number representing whether or not a pancake is burnt or unburnt.

Note that this is an **NP-HARD** problem. You may not make an approximation algorithm.

## Testcases

```
1b2b3b4u returns the following:
 1b|2b3b4u
 1u2b|3b4u
 2u|1b3b4u
 2b1b|3b4u
 1u2u3b|4u
 3u|2b1b4u
 3b2b1b|4u
 1u2u3u4u
4b3b2b1b returns the following:
 4b3b2b1b|
 1u2u3u4u
```

This is fastest-algorithm, so the minimal time complexity wins.

Comment: 32145 3'2145 1'2'345 21345 2'1345 1'2345 12345 Is [3,2,1,4,5] at most 6?

Comment: Is this a good explanation?

Comment: @awi Nice, much better! Some images might make it even better.

Comment: I found a visualization of the problem at one point, might link that. Could someone confirm what the solutions for the examples are?

Comment: Found some solutions by brute force. Is this good?

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91408/56656).

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexicographical sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243754/lexicographical-sum)

Comment: Bigger test cases would be helpful.

Comment: how big @ophact?

Comment: Something like 386 would be great

Comment: Isn't it called Lexicographical instead of Lexical? Either way, not sure why it got so many downvotes, unless it was for a previous versions that were already corrected, or it could use a short explanation of Lexicographical order in general. You may also want to write out the `n=9` example a bit more perhaps. E.g. "For sum `n=9` the following  strictly decreasing arrays are possible: `[[9],[8,1],[7,2],[6,3],[5,4],[6,2,1],[5,3,1],[4,3,2]]`. Putting these in lexicographical order: `[[4,3,2],[5,3,1],[5,4],[6,2,1],[6,3],[7,2],[8,1],[9]]`, the first `[4,3,2]` will be the final output."

Comment: I think you should clarify more explicitly that the array is strictly decreasing and therefore cannot contain duplicate elements. At first it wasn't obvious to me why the output isn't always just `[1, 1, 1, 1, ...]`

Comment: sry @KevinCruijssen and pxeger i did not have time to check ur msgs yet as i was sleeping thx for the feedback! i will change the challenge accordingly

Answer (score 2):

## Social distance the graph

Given a connected, undirected graph like so, where various nodes are connected to each other:

[image]

Select as many nodes as possible such that no two selected nodes are adjacent.

[image]

^ made by clumsy by-hand greedy algorithm, tell me if I stuffed this up. The red ones are the selected ones.

You should output the maximal number of points for which this is possible.

You can take the graph in any reasonable form - as an adjacency matrix, a list of edges, a list of nodes, etc.

The graph will have at least one edge, and no more than one edge connecting two points.

### Testcases

[image] -> 2
[image] -> 3
[image] -> 5
[image] -> 5

Comment: This is called the [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)), though I like the social distancing name

Comment: What are the assumptions on the graph we can make? E.g. will the graph be connected, without self-loops, without multiple edges joining same vertices, with at least one edge?

Comment: @pajonk You can assume all of those.

Comment: Could you please edit all of that into the question? I bet there will be a question about it when it gets posted (especially connectivity, less confident about self-loops) ;-)

Comment: @pajonk Already did.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I missed the "connected" added at the beginning.

Comment: Could you clarify that in your example the red ones are the one's you selected, not the purple ones? I had to work out which was which. Also, why are some of the nodes in the diagrams bigger than others?

Comment: For the second test case, would it be possible to rearrange the nodes so the lines don't all cross in the same place? Just for the avoidance of doubt to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

## String table

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243944/generate-this-string-table)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/print-output-the-l-phabet), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229414/generate-this-number-table)

Comment: *please* leave stuff in the sandbox for more than two hours.

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement a very simple ALU using only NAND gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/244195/104836)

Comment: `O0-O7`? Isn't it `O0-O3`?

Comment: Oh, yes. My mistake: a previous revision of the challenge had a data width of 8 bits. I will correct that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Convert from Two's Complement to Decimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245492/convert-from-twos-complement-to-decimal)

Comment: May we assume at most one leading zero? If not, please add a test-case covering this.

Comment: I was assuming not, so I will add a test case.

Comment: Are we allowed to copy the example answer XD

Comment: Well, if there are no better solutions in Mathematica, it could become a community wiki solution, and the approach could certainly be adapted to another language.

Answer (score 2):

[Spaceship shooter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245454/spaceship-shooter)

Comment: This looks good as it is; it doesn't need to be made harder. However, you can always _make_ it harder. So, if you _want_ to make it harder, go ahead! The more challenging the challenge, the more enjoyable it is (at least, until it becomes impossible)!

Comment: Ah ok thx @SylvesterKruin ig ill leave it as it is, i dont want to overcomplicate

Answer (score 2):

## Is it a base-\$\infty\$ prime?

To explain how base-\$\infty\$ numbers work, let's  look at how base 10 arithmetic works. We can view a base 10 number as a list of digits (numbers). So `123` is `[1,2,3]` and so on. When we add numbers, we use the standard long addition, meaning we add digit by digit, carrying if necessary. For example, `123+798`:

```
  ₁₁ 
  123
+ 798
-----
  921
```

Similarly, multiplication can be done using long multiplication. For example, `123*798`:

```
    123
*   798
-------
    984
  1107
+ 861
-------
  98154
```

Now, like the name suggest, base-\$\infty\$ numbers have infinitely many possible digits. Therefore we can represent a base-\$\infty\$ number as a list of integers. For lists consisting of only non-negative numbers, addition and multiplication are straightforward. For example, `[19,53,1]+[8,4]=[19,53,1]+[0,8,4]=[19,61,5]` and `[1,2]*[3,4]=[1,2]*[3,0]+[1,2]*[4]=[3,6,0]+[4,8]=[3,10,8]`. When restricted to non-negative numbers, carrying doesn't occur.

Negative numbers however spice things up. Let's look first how `[-1]` works. Let's see what happens when we add `[1]` to it:

`[-1]+[1]=[1,0]`

We get `[1,0]`. Before explaining how this works, it may be helpful to look at a related example in base-10:

`9 + 1 = 10`

Do you see the similarities? Nine is just ten *minus one*. Anyways, what is happening is that when you cross the boundary from the negatives to the positives, you carry one, so you end up with `[1,0]` where the one is carried.

Let's see what happens when we add `[-1]` to `[-1]`. We can reason in this way:

`[-1]+[-1]=[-1]+[1]+[-2]=[1,0]+[-2]=[1,-2]`

Here is the related base-10 example:

`9 + 9 = 18`

Ok, here is a more complicated example

`[1,3,-2,-3,6]+[1,5,-1]=[1,4,0,3,5]`

And the base-10 equivalent

`13876+159=14035`

For singular non-negative integers, multiplication works as you'd expect:

`[3]*[1,-2,3]=[1,-2,3]+[1,-2,3]+[1,-2,3]=[5,-6,9]`

For singular negative integers, we can use the following trick:

`[-3]*[1,-2,3]=([1,0] - [3])*[1,-2,3]=[1,0]*[1,-2,3]-[3]*[1,-2,3]=[1,-2,3,0]-[5,-6,9]=[1,-8,9,-9]`

where `a-b=c` iff `b+c=a` (subtraction is well defined as long as `a>=b`).

Here is a base-10 example:

`[-1]*[-1]=[-2,1]`
`9*9=81`

For multiplying with longer numbers, we just distribute the addition:

`[a,b,c]*[d,e,f]=[a,0,0]*[d,e,f]+[b,0]*[d,e,f]+[c]*[d,e,f]=[a]*[d,e,f,0,0]+[b]*[d,e,f,0]+[c]*[d,e,f]`

Basically just doing long multiplication.

## Primes

A prime number is a number which cannot be expressed as a non-trivial product. A non-trivial product is a product which doesn't contain the multiplicative identity (`[1]`). By convention, the multiplicative identity is not a prime.

Your task is to take a base-\$\infty\$ number as input and decide if it's a prime.

## Rules

Standard [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules apply. You may assume that the input doesn't contain leading zeros. You may choose whether the additive identity (zero) is represented as `[]` or `[0]`.

## Mathematical definition of addition and multiplication

Addition:

```
[] + b = b
a + [] = a
[...ia,la] + [...ib,lb] = [...(ia + ib + carry(la, lb)), la+lb]
```

where

```
carry(a,b) = [(a < 0 and b < 0) or (a + b >= 0 and min(a,b) != 0]
```

Multiplication:

```
[] * b = []
[..ia, 0] * b = [...(ia*b),0]
[..ia,-a] * b = [...(ia + [1]), 0]*b - [a]*b
[..ia, a + 1] * b = [..ia, a]*b + b
```

Where `a-b` is the unique solution to `b+x=a` (guaranteed to be well defined when using the above definitions)

## Test cases:

```
[0] -> False
[1] -> False
[2] -> True
[3] -> True
[4] -> False
[5] -> True
[6] -> False
[7] -> True
[8] -> False
[9] -> False
[10] -> False
[11] -> True
[12] -> False
[-12] -> True
[-11] -> True
[-10] -> True
[-9] -> True
[-8] -> True
[-7] -> True
[-6] -> True
[-5] -> True
[-4] -> True
[-3] -> True
[-2] -> True
[-1] -> True
[1,0] -> True
[1,1] -> True
[1,2] -> True
[1,3] -> True
[1,4] -> True
[1,-4] -> False
[1,-3] -> True
[1,-2] -> False
[1,-1] -> True
todo add more test cases
```

Comment: Isn't this just the set of integer polynomials with nonnegative leading coefficient in disguise?

Comment: @Nitrodon Yes, it is

Comment: how are your challenges so good? +1 for nice challenge!

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw an ASCII envelope](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245538/111322)

Comment: Wow your're a good challenge poster. nice challenge!

Comment: But i think you can remove the last 2 points under rules as they are sort of standard code golf rules and ascii art rules, and u might wanna include "trailing spaces are allowed"

Comment: @DialFrost Thanks for the feedback! I'll edit it according to your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

## What's the Missing Code?

[Cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245701/110951)
[Robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245702/110951)

Comment: Now _this_ sounds like fun! Just one question: wouldn't it add more to the challenge if you _didn't_ tell the robbers where each letter was removed? I feel like knowing where the missing characters are would make it too easy, especially since the cops are trying to create as short code as possible (so that they win). Do you think it would make it too easy?

Comment: I thought about this, but I came to the conclusion that it would make it easier for the robbers to simply go to the start of the program, and write `print(...); end program`. However, on thinking about it again, this would make it easier for the cops to reduce the characters removed while keeping the answer non-obvious, which would prevent the robbers from doing this. I will consider this and perhaps change the question.

Comment: Ohh.... I see what you mean. But that could be part of the cops' challenge: making the code complicated enough, with few enough characters removed, so that the robbers couldn't do that. But yes, your reasoning makes sense now. In that case, either way would be fine. I'm looking forward to when this is posted on the main site!

Comment: I think it is too easy for the robbers in its current state, so I will edit it to include your suggestion: I think that as long as the cops remove few enough characters, it will be impossible for the robbers to do this.

Comment: If your `int("5")` example is run in the Python shell (as opposed to in a program), the output is `5`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

## [Batt to the Basics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245671/111322)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wash clothes as quickly as possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245765/79857)

Comment: Can you add test cases?

Answer (score 2):

## [There's more than one way to skin a set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247326) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [set-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-partitions) [integer-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions)

Comment: You may want to clarify that when summing the subset, one may take a number only once and that the order doesn't matter. Also subjective suggestion: allow only inputs of length >1 (or even >2).

Comment: Description could be clearer, possibly something like "given a set S of integers, output all the integers that are the sum of multiple subsets of S" would be less wordy and clearer, also outputting a "set" is probably not necessary, as I feel that whitespace delimited strings or simple lists would work, especially since not all langs have a specific concept of a set

Comment: also possibly add a few comments onto the test cases to explain them a bit more, eg. on test case 3 adding a comment like "21 can be 10+11 or 9+12"

Comment: @des54321 It's pretty standard that "outputting a set" doesn't literally mean a builtin set type, it just means some kind of list-y thing

Comment: @pxeger, fair enough, although you may want to explicitly specify strings with just whitespace separators if you want to allow that as output, as especially with the current format of your testcases that does feel slightly like its not allowed

Answer (score 2):

## Translate Text into Matoran

The [Matoran Alphabet](https://bionicle.fandom.com/wiki/Matoran_Alphabet) is the alphabet used by many of the characters in the Bionicle universe.

[image: Matoran Alphabet]

Your challenge is to create a program or function that takes a string as input and creates an image of the input written in the Matoran alphabet.

The input will only consist of uppercase letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), and spaces. You may instead take input in lowercase.

### Glyphs

As you can probably notice, the alphabet comprises glyphs made up of circles and straight lines.

For the sake of this challenge, let's define each glyph as a circle of radius 4 units (8 x 8), with some internal designs. The internal designs  of letters can be any of:

- Vertical Line at position 2, 4, or 6 (either full length or half)
- Horizontal Line equivalent to above
- Circle of radius 1, centered at [2, 2], [2, 6], [6, 2], or [6, 6]
- Any of the above rotated by 45 degrees about the centre

Number glyphs work slightly differently; they always have a circle of radius 1 in the centre. For numbers 0 - 5, the glyph has evenly spaced spokes between the circles, starting from the top. For numbers greater than 5, the glyph has an additional circle of radius 2 in the centre, and the number of spokes is 6 less than the number.

Here is a diagram of the glyphs in spec, any glyphs with 45 degree rotations have an orange grid.

[image: Matoran Alphabet]

For drawing the glyphs, any line stroke in the range (0, 1) can be used. Glyphs can be kerned (space between adjacent glyphs) any amount from 0 - 4 units. Spaces should be 8 units wide (in addition to kerning).

This is a code-golf challenge, so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: This does seem like pretty interesting challenge, although I would recommend a clearer image of the characters of the Matoran alphabet, and probably a more rigorous definition of the shapes of each of the characters (eg. defining the positions/lengths/radii/etc of the inner circles/lines in terms of the radius of the exterior circle)

Comment: @des54321 Thank you! I added some specification around the characters. Do you think this is sufficient, or should I include a written definition of each glyph?

Comment: That looks pretty good! I'd suggest leaving this challenge up on the sandbox for a bit longer to see if anyone else has suggestions, but as things stand now this seems a very well specified and fairly interesting challenge

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll leave it a couple of days then post it.

Answer (score 2):

## Will this makina program halt?

[makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina) is a cell-based esolang composed of automata which move around a grid. These automata follow paths of instructions that direct their movement. Your task is to, given a makina program *using only the below instructions* (so a subset of normal makina) as input, output two distinct values depending on whether or not it is a loop. (If program flow comes to an arrow character that it has already visited then the program is a loop.)

### Instructions

- `^>v<` These instructions (arrows) set the direction of the automaton to the direction they point in.
- `I` This instruction halts automata going up or down, but does nothing to ones going left or right.
- `H` This instruction halts automata going left or right, but does nothing to ones going up or down.
- `O` This instruction does nothing to the automaton, acting like a sort of 4-way intersection.

All other characters halt the automaton, as does exiting the bounds of the program. The automaton starts in the top-left corner going right.

### Testcases

### Truthy

```
>>>v
v<<<
```

```
OOOv
H<<<
v
```

### Falsey

```
>>>v
^<<<
```

```
>v
^O<
>^
```

```
>>>v
v<I<
H>^
>^
```

```
>>>>v
v <<<
```

```
OOOv
H<<<
v
```

Comment: "All other characters halt the automaton" So arbitrary characters different from `>v<^HIO` can be part of the input? If so, this should be reflected in the test cases. (Personally, I'd only allow valid characters in the input.)

Comment: Also the current last two Falsy test cases actually halt and are probably a cop-paste error from the Truthy cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [Get the trends of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246405/get-the-trends-of-an-array)

Comment: Is there any specifications prevent the program from outputting `[[1,1], [1,2], [2,3]]` for `[1,1,2,3]`? Maybe you should add some texts about "you should generate fewest possible trends" or something like it.

Comment: @tsh Good idea. Added.

Answer (score 2):

## Convert to Shorthand ([Part 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246611/convert-to-shorthand-part-1), [Part 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246641/convert-to-shorthand-part-2))

Comment: Conjunction points of O P X Y may be ambiguous.

Comment: @tsh I am thinking of allowing multiple correct answers for the same input. To make it slightly more precise I have added more rules and improved the examples.

Comment: I feel like this are actually two challenges in one: 1. transcribe to the weird alphabet 2. make this "interconnected". I suggest splitting to two challenges.

Comment: I see you posted the first part, please edit this post or post a new one so that we can discuss the details of the second part (if you like).

Comment: @pajonk Thank you for the interest. I am thinking of putting all details in the same question to avoid clashing of data. This question is still the umbrella goal I am trying to achieve with it. I will be editing details once I get more suggestion from the posted questions

Answer (score 2):

## [Sequence of integers not the sum of powers of earlier terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246671/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Write a (simplified) BitCycle Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247276/write-a-simplified-bitcycle-interpreter)

Answer (score 2):

## Modular tetration

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

[Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) is the operation of repeated exponentiation. That is \$ ^{n}a = a ^ {. ^ {. ^ {.^a}}} \$, with \$ a \$ appearing \$ n \$ times.

Tetration grows extremely fast - \$ ^6 2 \$ would take significantly more digits to write then there are atoms in the known universe.

However, to work with big numbers, we can operate on them modulo some number \$ m \$.

Your task is to calculate \$ ^n a \mod m \$, with integer \$ 1 < a,n < m \$.

### Rules

- You may use any consistent [reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- The complexity of your answer must be \$ O(m) \$, where \$ m \$ is the modulus. In particular, you can't calculate \$ ^{n}a \$ with arbitrary precision and then modulo by \$ m \$.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
- Your algorithm must work for all values, but it's allowed for your program to fail due to integer overflow.

### Test cases

The format for the test cases is `a n m -> answer` (however, you can take your input in any order)
[**Sandbox note:** TODO - there's an error in my program]

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I don't really know how to compute \$O\$ here, but would [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714635/6713210) satisfy the requirement on \$O(m)\$?

Comment: @pajonk it depends on the implementation. If you calculate euler's totient by going over all numbers from 1 to m and calculating the gcd it wouldn't, since calculating the gcd is logarithmic time, so it'll be \$ \Theta(m \log m) \$. If you calculate it by factoring \$ m \$ in \$ o(m) \$ time then it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Convert Alpha-2 to Alpha-3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247294/107299)

Comment: I liked the back story, personally.

Answer (score 2):

## [I want 8 bits for every character!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character)

Answer (score 2):

## Generate Fibonacci Primes Quickly

Unsurprisingly, [fibonacci primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime) are primes that are also Fibonacci numbers. There are currently 34 known Fibonacci primes and an additional 15 probable Fibonacci primes. For the purpose of this challenge, the Fibonacci numbers are the sequence \$F_n\$ defined as \$F_1 = 1\$, \$F_2 = 1\$, and \$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}\$, and a number is considered prime if it passes a probabilistic prime test with a probability of being incorrect of less than \$2^{-32}\$. For example, since a \$k\$ round Miller-Rabin test has an error probability of \$4^{-k}\$, a 16 round Miller-Rabin test is sufficient to prove primality for the purpose of this challenge.

### Submissions:

The goal of this challenge is to write a full program that calculates every Fibonacci prime and its index in the Fibonacci series as fast as possible.

Submissions shall be a full program, complete with instructions for building and running it. Submissions must be in a language freely available for noncommercial use and capable of running on Windows 10, and users must be prepared to provide installation instructions for that language. External libraries are permitted, with the same caveats that apply to languages.

Primes will be output by writing to stdout with a simple binary format, that has a little-endian byte order:

```
[8 bytes- index into the Fibonacci series]
[8 bytes- length of the Fibonacci prime, in bytes]
[? bytes- the Fibonacci prime, as a byte array]
```

### Scoring

The programs will be run on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU with 8 threads, avx-2 support, and 24 Gigabytes of ram. The largest prime that can be correctly reached in one minute wins. Tiebreaker is the time taken to reach the largest value. Programs that tamper with my computer or the testing program will be disqualified. Programs that error or otherwise fail to produce the correct output will be judged based on the furthest Fibonacci prime reached before they failed.

see also: [A005478](https://oeis.org/A005478), [A001605](https://oeis.org/A001605)

The test program can be found [here](https://github.com/Aiden2207/fibonacci_primes). Additionally, there is an example program [here](https://github.com/Aiden2207/fibonacci_primes/tree/master/competitors/example).

### Meta

The test program is now completed and posted, but I still have a little documentation to write. I chose the output format to be simple, and so that answers wouldn't have to worry about formatting integers quickly. Is there anything I need to improve clarity-wise?

tags: [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [fibonnacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonnacci) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Comment: Since there are only 34 (?+15) of them, how will you stop a program from hard-coding these, and then starting looking for larger ones from the last of them onwards?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen tweaked the question to use "calculate" instead of "list", which has worked for other challenges in the past. I also posted the controller.

Comment: How is the "error bound" of a "probable prime" defined?

Comment: @pxeger I hopefully clarified what I meant, by error bound I meant error probability.

Answer (score 2):

## Convert Klingon romanization to `pIqaD` [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

### Context

Klingon is a constructed language from *Star Trek*. It has two writing systems: a not-very-good Latin alphabet (with case distinctions, `I` being different from `l`, ...) and its own script, called `pIqaD`.

### Task

Convert the bad<sup>*[disputed - discuss]*</sup> Klingon romanization into `pIqaD`. Here's a CSV (the `pIqaD` [or, if you don't have a font for it, boxes or nothing] is in the second column and the Unicode hexadecimal codes are in the third):

```
a,,f8d0
b,,f8d1
ch,,f8d2
D,,f8d3
e,,f8d4
gh,,f8d5
H,,f8d6
I,,f8d7
j,,f8d8
l,,f8d9
m,,f8da
n,,f8db
ng,,f8dc
o,,f8dd
p,,f8de
q,,f8df
Q,,f8e0
r,,f8e1
S,,f8e2
t,,f8e3
tlh,,f8e4
u,,f8e5
v,,f8e6
w,,f8e7
y,,f8e8
',,f8e9
```

Be careful not to mix up `q` and `Q`, they are different letters in Klingon!

### Input and output

Strings! or your language's equivalent. You can assume that the input contains no characters not in Klingon (incl. miscapitalized `dhis`) or numbers or punctuation.

## Scoring

Lowest byte count wins, as always.

---

suggestions? :)

Comment: I like it! It seems ready for publication.

Comment: My browser shows only `⍰` in the second column of the csv. Maybe add a link to TIO or other external page, which will render it correctly. If possible, you may also add UTF codes for those characters.

Comment: @pajonk i added the unicode codes :)

Answer (score 2):

## [`lol` is an ambigram, `dad` isn't](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248070/66833)

Comment: I think you mean "rotated", not "reversed". [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62183/will-it-ambigram), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142248/im-symmetric-not-palindromic), but not a dupe of either.

Comment: I think using the word "palindrome" is misleading here. Palindrome is specifically for reversing right-to-left, not rotating. Also, please specify what kind of rotation is required (180 deg around the center of the word, isn't it?) and add some longer test-cases with various length. Please also specify what to do with empty string. Suggestion: make this [tag:decision-problem], not a "filter a list", because now it requires some needless boring boilerplate code.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 2):

## [Fill the rectangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248186/108879)

Answer (score 2):



Answer (score 2):

## [How much more to a repdigit?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248230/108879)

Comment: These are more commonly referred to as [repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit)

Answer (score 2):

## [Is it a heapable sequence?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248752/is-it-a-heapable-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

## [Enumerate all pure sets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248715/enumerate-all-pure-sets)

Comment: [tag:sequence] IO?

Comment: @pxeger Good idea :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Find the walls!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248896)

Answer (score 2):

## Interpret BigTalk

[Talk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190819/talk-interpreter/) is a language which takes a single bit of input and has four commands:

- `00` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 0.
- `01` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 1.
- `10` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 0.
- `11` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 1.

These can be interpreted as replacement commands. We're going to extend that concept to positive integers, and make the language more complicated.

The language we're going to be defining is called BigTalk. It has an accumulator, which is a list of positive integers, initially set to only the input.

Programs are a series of commands. Each command is a pair of lists of integers, like ([24, 2], [32, 1]), and means to replace the first as a sequence with the second, as many times as it occurs.

The program runs repeatedly until the accumulator does not change. Finally, the accumulator is output.

For example, with the input `[5, 5, 5, 5]` and the program `([5, 5], [3, 2, 1]), ([3], [5]), ([2, 1, 5], [5, 1, 2])`, the list goes:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1]
[5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Your challenge is to interpret this language. You may take input and program in any reasonable format.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

In the format of `input, commands`.

```
[5, 5, 5, 5], ([5, 5], [3, 2, 1]), ([3], [5]), ([2, 1, 5], [5, 1, 2]) -> [5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[4], ([4], [4, 4]) -> Infinite loop
[2, 19, 13], ([13, 19], [2]) -> [2, 19, 13]
[39, 1, 23], ([1], [39, 23]), ([39, 39], [1, 1]), ([23, 23], [1]) -> [39, 23, 39, 23, 39, 23]
```

This language may be Turing-complete, and I have a +50 bounty for someone who proves it either way.

Answer (score 2):

## [How far from binary?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248922/how-far-from-binary)

Comment: Your description doesn't quite match your test cases.  It should probably say that the *absolute value of* `n-m` is composed only of `1`s and `0`s.  Since negative numbers have `-`.

Comment: @WheatWizard Why is it necessary? -101 is a signed binary.

Comment: `-101` is not a binary string.  It might be *reasonable* to interpret the intended way, but I certainly think it's more reasonable to interpret it another way.  I don't see any harm in being explicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw the Progress Pride flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249373/draw-the-progress-pride-flag/)

Comment: This is a really nice flag. It breaks one of the "golden rules of flag design" (no more than 3 colours) but that's the point. And harder to draw than it looks because you can't just draw a triangle for the brown and black. The spec is slightly inconsistent: the height calculated from the diagonal strip width is (340+170+170)*2 = 1360 which differs from the height calculated from the horizontal strip width 224 * 6 = 1344 so you might wat to fix that.

Comment: I think the spec is reasonably clear but I have a few suggestions: 1. delete the word "obviously" - too patronizing. BTW this is covered by one of the standard loopholes here on Meta - it's always good to reference them. 2. So the minimum size is 1100 x 672? I recommend you state it explicitly rather than saying "only half" . "Exactly" is a strong word (especially when 170/sqrt 2 is actually 120.20815 ) - I recommend an error of 1 pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the response I’ll fix this on Wednesday

Answer (score 2):

## [Flood fill by distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249085/flood-fill-by-distance)

Comment: I suggest using a different character than `O` for obstacles, because it looks too much like `0`. Maybe `#`?

Comment: In your third code block, the last two grids still use `O` intead of `X` in two places each.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nest some addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249194)

- There's a natural follow-up with the other possible addition operator, where the order of application is reversed, i.e. \$\operatorname{add2}\overparen{\underparen a}\overparen{\underparen b} f=\left(\overparen{\underparen b} f\right)\circ\left(\overparen{\underparen a} f\right)\$.

Comment: Even though I've dabbled in similar contexts before, I would have been helped by a reminder to think of everything in terms of functions which act on functions.

Comment: It looks like the multiplication and exponentiation rules are part of the "Task", but if I understand right they're really an additional comment on **add** or a hint which could be useful for understanding / implementing / verifying behavior.

Comment: @thejonymyster **add** is binary, since it expects two curried arguments.

Comment: May I take input as \$x_0,\dots,x_a\$ without taking the integer \$a\$?

Comment: @alephalpha that should be [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442)

Comment: I think the \$ \mathsf {formatting} \$ might be clearer if you denoted "Church numeral of \$ n \$" as something like \$ [n] \$. Because at the moment, it's not entirely clear that \$ \mathsf {a^b} \$ means \$ [a^b] \$ and not \$ [a]^{[b]} \$ (which doesn't make any sense)

Comment: @pxeger What do you think about \$\overparen{\underparen n}\$ / \$\overparen{\underparen{a^b}}\$ (or maybe only over)? I feel like braces add a bit too much clutter.

Comment: @att Sure, both work fine

Comment: @thejonymyster I think "where ∘ denotes function composition" should be sufficient (it's also defined as the multiplication rule)

Comment: Oh, i skimmed right over that. I guess my friend just can't read :P

Answer (score 2):

## Parse this handy graph format

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

There's a great number of ways to represent directed graphs like the following:
[image: Three examples of directed graphs]

Most representations are tailored towards being easy to work with, either for humans (like the picture above) or for computers (like an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) representation). A middle ground I found useful in the past is this format:

```
        A -> B <-> C                A -> B -> C -> A           A -> C -> D; B <-> C <-> E
```

It is basically a condensed edge list, which is still relatively close to a graphical representation (good for humans) but not too hard to parse for a computer.

The goal in this challenge is to take a string representing a graph in this format as input and output a list of the graph's nodes and a list of the graph's edges.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to use as few bytes as possible in the language of your choice.

#### Input specification

- Each *node* has a unique name consisting of alphabetical letters, for example `A`, `b`, or `Node`. It is also fine if you only support upper or lower case names.
- Three types of *arrows* can appear: `->`, `<-`, and `<->`.
- A *chain* is formed by a sequence starting with node and then alternating between arrows and nodes, for example `A -> B <- C` or also just `A`.
- A chain may be followed by another chain with `;` as a separator in between.
- Between node names and the arrows and the semicolon can be any number of *spaces* (including zero).
- Self-loops are possible, i.e., `A -> A` describes an arrow from node `A` to itself.
- You may assume the input string is a valid encoding of a graph.

#### Output specification

- The list of nodes can be returned or printed in any reasonable format and order, e.g., `A, B, C`, `["A", "B", "C"]`, `A\nB\nC`, ...
- Edges are represented as ordered tuples in any reasonable format, e.g., `("A", "B")` or `A B` for the edge `A -> B` and `("D", "C")` or `D C` for the edge `C <- D`.
- The list of directed edges can again be output in any reasonable format.

#### Test cases

```
"A -> B <-> C"               : ["A", "B", "C"], [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "B")]
"A -> B -> C -> A"           : ["A", "B", "C"], [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "A")]
"A -> C -> D; B <-> C <-> E" : ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], [("A", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "B"), ("C", "E"), ("E", "C")]
"AA<->BB"                    : ["AA", "BB"], [("AA", "BB"), ("BB", "AA")]
"A;B"                        : ["A", "B"], []
" "                          : [], []
"   A   <- B  ;  C  "        : ["A", "B", "C"], [("B", "A")]
"A -> A; B <- B"             : ["A", "B"], [("A", "A"), ("B", "B")]
```

---

##### Sandbox question:

Given that this is foremost a [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) question, I'm tempted to drop the validity assumption and require answers to raise an error if the input does not follow the spec. What do you think, would that still be fun?

Comment: Definitely don't require validity. That makes the challenge two quite different challenges, and is in no way necessary.

Comment: ^ probably a typo, but 100% you should allow users to assume validity. Don't require validity *checking*.

Answer (score 2):

## [Is it shuffled FizzBuzz?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249235/is-it-shuffled-fizzbuzz)

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement Binary Exponentiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249463/implement-binary-exponentiation)

Comment: interestingly you can do the same thing with binary or peasant multiplication. actually any associative operation.

Answer (score 2):

## Is this a squashed series? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given a string of digits, determine whether it is the concatenation of at least two ascending consecutive integers. (in decimal, with no leading zeroes)

For example, the string `7891011` is valid, because it's the concatenation of the sequence `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`.

However, the string `54` could only be formed by concatenating `[5, 4]` (which is not ascending), or  `[54]` (which does not have at least two numbers in it), so it is not valid.

(This challenge is essentially asking "Is it a valid input to [Decipher a squashed series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249208)")

You should output using two distinct values of your choice to represent "valid" and "not valid".

Take care with leading zeroes: for example, `809` is not valid, even though it could be decomposed into `[8, 09]`, because `09` is not a valid decimal integer.

You may assume the input does not start with a `0`, and has a length of at least 2. The input will also only contain digits (and not `-`, so you don't need to handle negative numbers).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Valid

```
1234
7891011
293031323334
9991000
```

Invalid

```
54
66
28
3131
809
```

Valid numbers are given by [A035333](https://oeis.org/A035333) in the OEIS.

## Meta

- Is this interesting enough? (It was just a byproduct of [Decipher a squashed series](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24927))
- Is my handling of the `809` case good? Or should I allow either output for inputs like that?

Comment: In Brachylog, this would be the exact same answer as your previous challenge, but I guess it’s mostly because of the declarative nature of the language. I don’t know if that’s interesting enough compared to the othe challenge with other language paradigms.

Comment: Fwiw, in 05AB1E it isn't the exact same answer, but it's a pretty trivial change. My initial answer was `.œ.Δ¥P`; and it would be `.œʒ¥P}g` without the `809` test case or `.œʒ¥P}ïJQO` with the `809` test case (both outputting `2`/`1` for truthy/falsey respectively). So the `8,09` test case definitely adds something interesting, although 05AB1E's `"09"==9` being truthy makes it a bit more tricky than in most other languages I'd imagine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Solve a Card Suit Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249863/solve-a-card-suit-puzzle)

Answer (score 2):

## [Is it an ordinal?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249479/is-it-an-ordinal)

Comment: An interesting variation could be an [tag:open-ended-function] [tag:sequence] with the task being to generate every ordinal. Although I don't know if there would be a better way to answer that than smushing this decision problem and a "generate every ragged list" algorithm.

Comment: @pxeger There's no way to generate every ordinal.  There are uncountable ordinals, as well as countable but incomputable ordinals.

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw this fractal generated by applying Newton's method to cosh(x) - 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249439)

Comment: ooh seems really fun

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw the USA flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249512/draw-the-usa-flag)

Comment: "then your score is half of your program's length" is generally not welcomed here.

Answer (score 2):

## [Convert from Greeklish to modern Greek](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249706/convert-from-greeklish-to-modern-greek)

Comment: I like natural language challenges, however it seems a bit boring.  I feel like we must have a few challenges already that are a substitution cypher with digraphs, and it probably isn't really doing anything new there.

Comment: @WheatWizard I understand that character substitution challenges do exist in the site. However, from my search of the sandbox, there isn't one for Greek, so it's somewhat original. Therefore, I am considering to post this. If this goes any well, I will also consider posting a harder natural language Greek challenge ;)

Comment: I just don't think that it being Greek actually makes the task any more interesting.  Like it's neat, but the task is just a very simple substitution.  If you have a harder challenge about Greek I'd say go with that one first.

Comment: @WheatWizard Since I made the effort to post and polish this a bit, I will post it. If it doesn't receive as much upvotes due to its unoriginality so be it. This site runs for many years and its hard to come up with something 100% original. Personally, I think its a solid challenge. Finally, I will also link to other related challenges, as I've seen quite recently on non-original challenges.

Answer (score 2):

## [Every possible pairing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249868)

Comment: Seems a little on the simple side I think.  Might be a duplicate, but if it's not I think it's likely to score very well. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement level-index addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251365/81203)

Answer (score 2):

## Infinite Fibonacci word [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

The famous Fibonacci sequence of integers is defined as follows:

\$
F_0 = 0 \\
F_1 = 1 \\
F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}
\$

But what if we use this same recurrence relation to produce an infinite sequence of strings? Instead of addition, we'll use concatenation. We'll also change the base case slightly:

\$ F_0 = \$ `0`
\$ F_1 = \$ `01`
\$ F_n = F_{n-1}F_{n-2} \$

The first few strings are:

```
0
01
010
01001
01001010
0100101001001
...
```

Each of these "words" is a prefix of the next, so they are all prefixes of the single infinite word \$ F_\infty = \$

```
010010100100101001010010010100100101001010010010100101001001010010010100101001001010010010100101001...
```

Your task is to output this infinite string as a sequence; you may choose to use any two distinct values to use for 0 and 1.

As with standard [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, you may choose to either:

- Take an input \$ n \$ and output the \$ n \$th item in the sequence
- Take an input \$ n \$ and output the first \$ n \$ item
- Output the sequence indefinitely, e.g. using a generator

and you may use 0-based or 1-based indexing for \$ n \$.

This string can be defined in many different ways; its OEIS entry [A003849](https://oeis.org/A003849) and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) have more information.

Errors due to floating-point imprecision are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Seems very similar to the infinite quote escaping sequence

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should be [tag:binary] - `0` and `1` have no special meaning, they can be replaced by any symbol

Comment: @mousetail Yes, in fact the Fibonacci word can also be formed using a string rewriting rule like the quote sequence. In this case it's replacing `0` with `01`, and `1` with `0`.

Comment: This is a interesting challenge, however, of the 2 challenges I think the other one is slightly more interesting.

Comment: @mousetail Who's to say we can't have both? I think they're definitely not duplicates, because both have multiple different approaches, only one of which somewhat overlaps.

Comment: Fair enough, though I'd suggest to post it after the other challenge to acknowledge the inspiration

Comment: @mousetail It was not deliberately inspired by that challenge at all. (Maybe subliminally, because I had *seen* that challenge perviously?). But I learnt about the Fibonacci sequence independently while browsing Wikipedia.

Comment: I think you should specify if floating-point errors are allowed, since some approaches will probably use the golden ratio

Comment: @CommandMaster I've added a note about that, but AFAICT there aren't any direct methods to make the string using φ

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223325/55372)

Comment: @pxeger the OEIS entry says "a(n) = floor((n+2)*r) - floor((n+1)*r) where r=phi/(1+2*phi) and phi is the Golden Ratio."

Answer (score 2):

## [Is it a Valid Crossword Grid?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266004/is-it-a-valid-crossword-grid)

Comment: Suggested tags: crossword, grid

Comment: I don't see any clever algorithm for grid generation (that doesn't mean that there isn't one), so the answers are most likely use the brute-force method of generating all grids and checking their crosswordness - why not make it decision-problem then?

Comment: @pajonk I've modified the question as per your suggestion, but that makes it very similar to a [previously posed question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/883/crossword-grid-verification), so I'm unsure about this. I think there are some meaningful shortcuts to make the generation easier.

Comment: if you see shortcuts that make generation easier than brute-force, then ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Add parentheses to Polish notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250861/add-parentheses-to-polish-notation)

Comment: Suggested test-case with multi-digit numbers. Also, are the numbers guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: I think they should be limited to being positive.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the edge case that extra trash at the end needs removed (such as the `+ 1 2 3` test case). Of course, it's your challenge, just a suggestion. I prefer sticking to the actual problem, and not adding extra edge cases.

Comment: That was just a typo, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

## Change The Quotations as if in Microsoft Word

**META**: Posted

Comment: What to do with consecutive quotation marks? Or this won't ever be an input?

Comment: I've added a rule for that.

Comment: What will be the output for `'''` and `''''`? I other words, what is the precedence of the rules?

Comment: I've edited the rule I just added to accommodate these strings. Check it out.

Comment: How come `“` makes a brief appearance in rule 5 and nowhere else?

Comment: Oops, didn't delete that.

Answer (score 2):

## Carry-less sum given a base b

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251283/107561)

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## Are these numbers from the repeated application of this function?

Given a list of at least 3 positive integers \$L\$ and a function \$F\$ which takes a positive integer and returns a positive integer, determine if \$L\$ can be sorted such that each element of the list is the result of applying \$F\$ to the previous element (besides the first of course).

### Rules

- You may, of course, assume that \$F\$ always halts.
- You may also assume that \$F\$ will have no side-effects and is deterministic.
- You may take the \$F\$ as a [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A2447+black+box) in any reasonable format.
- Instead of taking \$F\$ as an input, you may take a second list \$M\$, which is the result of applying \$F\$ to each element of \$L\$.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest solution in bytes wins.

### Very simple worked out example

Inputting \$F(x)=x+1\$ and \$L=[5,4,3,2,1]\$ should output truthy, because \$L\$ can be rearranged into \$[1,2,3,4,5]\$, for which each element is the result of applying \$F\$ to the previous element: \$F(1)=2\$, \$F(2)=3\$, \$F(3)=4\$, and \$F(4)=5\$.

### More examples:

Truthy

```
F(x) = 2x,           L = [4,2,1,8]
F(x) = ceil(10/x),   L = [2,2,2,5,5,5]
F(X) = 3x+1,         L = [5,16,49,148]
F(x) = length(x),    L = [1,2,10,9876543210,1]
F(x) = 13            L = [13,13,13,13,14]
```

Falsy

```
F(x) = 2x,           L = [2,4,6,8]
F(x) = ceil(10/x),   L = [5,2,5,2,5,2,5,5]
F(X) = 3x+1,         L = [5,16,8,4,2,1,4]
F(x) = length(x),    L = [3,1,10,2]
F(x) = 13            L = [13,13,13,14,15]
```

## META

Is this ready to post or is it missing something / bad somewhere

Comment: You might want to clarify that black-box functions are allowed .See: [1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/92689) [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/13708#13708) [3](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/13707#13707) [4](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/13713#13713)

Comment: Almost certainly this has very little to do with functional programming (other than the fact that the program should take a function as input). On the other hand, there *is* a [proposed guideline for decision problem outputs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19202/78410).

Comment: You can refer to [these](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A2447+black+box) for black box function input methods. Currently the top two are accepted (predefined named functions and function arguments are both OK).

Comment: Is there a reason the function is part of the input, instead of the input being something like `L[i], F(L[i])`?

Comment: @CommandMaster Interesting, I suppose that has about the same effect. I will probably edit this to allow both input formats, though I'll have to think about it

Comment: Doesn't that trivialize the task though? It's just checking whether `L[1:] == M[:-1]` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Steffan you cant assume the order of the elements

Answer (score 2):

### write the "index by number" sequence

Imagine writing out positive integer numbers, and indexing each character in a 1-indexed array (indices read vertically on the top two rows, numbers read horizontally on the third):

```
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
```

Now, imagine if we skipped some numbers so we write the index at the point we start the next number:

```
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
one five ten fourteen twenty three thirty six fo
```

now, imagine that the first number doesn't have to be "one":

```
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
      seven thirteen twenty two thirty three for
```

#### Input

A single number from 1..999, in any format you like (`"1"`, `'1'`, `1`, `"one"` etc.)

This forms the starting number for the sequence

#### Output

A sequence of numbers, written long-hand in UK English ("one hundred **and** one" - no other differences), from (input)..(999) inclusive.

Code golf, usual rules.

Comment: 101 is "one hundred one" right?

Comment: @thejonymyster `one hundred and one`

Comment: Maybe you need include how to read number in _UK English_ in your post.

Comment: @tsh updated to try and clarify

Comment: 40 is "forty" in all standard English variants.

Comment: @pxeger TIL. Corrected in spec. Thanks

Comment: So we go up to the last number that starts before or exactly at 9999 even if it goes beyond 9999 once it's 'written'? 9999 is pretty high, btw. I think the challenge would be just as interesting but much easier to debug/verify with 999 (still high) or even 99 as the upper bound.

Comment: @Arnauld I don't want to end up creating an edge case that needs to be coded separately, so I'm happy to take guidance on how that would work - if the input is `9999` the output would be either `nine thousand nine hundred and ninety nine` or `n` (i.e. writing index #9999 then nothing above that) - which is better? Or best left optional?

Comment: @Arnauld aside from that, I'll lower the bounds to 999

Answer (score 2):

## [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This is less of a challenge proposal, and more of a idea for how to mesh the two title tags.

### A series of targeted fights

Consider a heads-up, 1v1 "game" between two king-of-the-hill style bots. However, unlike a general king-of-the-hill, where every bot plays against every other bot, we instead build bots that target specific bots to win against. An example of an existing bot would be [Low Blow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223223/66833) from [Cooperative Counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223202/66833), which aimed to identify it's opponent, then play counter to that bot. However, in this challenge, the bot wouldn't *have* to identify its opponent: it would *only* play one bot, the bot it was designed to beat.

The [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) aspect comes from this targeting:

- *User A* posts **Bot A**, targeting a provided example bot.
- *User B* then posts **Bot B**, targeting **Bot A**.
- *User C* then posts **Bot C**, targeting a second example bot.
- *User D* then posts **Bot D**, also targeting **Bot A**.

And so on, creating a "tree" of answers, each targeting a previous answer. Note that new answers don't have to target the latest, but can instead target any previous answer.

However, to prevent bots that "target", but don't actual perform well against their target, we'd need to require that it beats its target in \$X\%\$ of \$Y\$ battles, or else it is disqualified. Obviously, this prevents bots from being edited to improve themselves once targeted.

This begs the question: what is our scoring criteria? Clearly, depth from the root bots (provided in the challenge) must be a central part, as it's harder to create a bot the further down the chain you go. However, this doesn't differentiate between **Bot B** and **Bot D** in our example, despite the fact that **Bot D** beats **Bot A** \$82\%\$ of the time, vs **Bot B**'s meager win rate of \$61\%\$. Clearly, we should take winning rate into account. One potential score:

$$\text{Score} = \text{Win rate} \times \text{Depth}$$

where \$\text{Win rate}\$ is between \$0\$ (never wins) and \$1\$ (always wins).

---

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if this is a legitimate concern, but I'd be worried about rock-paper-scissors-like loops where A is always defeated by B, B is always defeated by C, and C is always defeated by A. In that case, it would always be advantageous to post a counter to the most recent post of A/B/C, which means that the score could go to infinity while resulting in very uninteresting bots. You could limit this by saying "no repeat answers", and people probably wouldn't do this in practice because it's boring, but it points to a possible failure mode.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 I don't think that's something to worry about. Ideally, the game would be designed such that, if Bot B beats Bot A the majority of the time, then, if Bot C defeats Bot B, it also must defeat Bot A. For example, in RPS, the "loop" style only occurs by defining the specific win/loss relationship. A 1v1 game with a points based scoring wouldn't encounter such a loop

Answer (score 2):

## [Print every Fool's Mate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252160/print-every-fools-mate/252161)

Answer (score 2):

## Generate a different sudoku

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sudoku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

---

### Task

Given a valid sudoku board, generate another sudoku board that isn't equivalent to the one inputted.

#### What do we consider as equivalent sudoku boards?

- they are the same,
- the digits are relabeled (eg. 2<->7 or 2->5->8->2),
- three-column or thee-row bands are permuted,
- the rows or columns within a band are permuted,
- one is a reflection of the other (horizontally, vertically or along any of the diagonals),
- one is a rotation of the other,
- or any combination of the above.

According to [Ed Russell and Frazer Jarvis](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudgroup.html) there are 5 472 730 538 essentially different sudoku classes.

#### What is a valid sudoku?

*(borrowed from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78210/55372))*

- Each row contains the digits from `1` to `9` exactly once.
- Each column contains the digits from `1` to `9` exactly once.
- Each of the nine 3x3 subgrids contains the digits from `1` to `9` exactly once.

### Rules

You may take input and output in any reasonable format, like a 9x9 matrix, list of rows/columns, a string of 81 digits etc.

Taking digits `0-8` instead of `1-9` is allowed, but please be consistent.

### Test cases

```
Input:
7 2 5 8 9 3 4 6 1
8 4 1 6 5 7 3 9 2
3 9 6 1 4 2 7 5 8
4 7 3 5 1 6 8 2 9
1 6 8 4 2 9 5 3 7
9 5 2 3 7 8 1 4 6
2 3 4 7 6 1 9 8 5
6 8 7 9 3 5 2 1 4
5 1 9 2 8 4 6 7 3
Example output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 3 1 5 6 4 8 9 7 
5 6 4 8 9 7 2 3 1
8 9 7 2 3 1 5 6 4 
3 1 2 6 4 5 9 7 8
6 4 5 9 7 8 3 1 2 
9 7 8 3 1 2 6 4 5

Input:

Example output:
```

## Meta

- Any mistakes in the test-cases?
- Is it sufficiently diffent to existing [sudoku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) challenges?
- Is it better as [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function) or a challenge to check whether two given grids are equivalent?

Comment: I think the [tag:decision-problem] version would be better, since that doesn't actually involve validating a sudoku board, which i believe is already a challenge. IMO anyway.

Comment: Are there any other possible sudoku equivalencies? Or is it safe to say that's it / that's all we care about ?

Comment: You might want to use the word "permuted" instead of "swapped" (I'm pretty sure that's what you mean)

Comment: Since you were asking if you should do a related decision-problem question instead: In case you want it, here's another related question. I don't know it's that great is as is for CGCC -- feels so specific it's maybe too overspecified, but just in case it's useful: "Generate a specified equivalent sudoku given inputs `originalSudoku`, `symbolPermutation`, `rowPermutations`, `columnPermutations`, `bandPermutation`, `stackPermutation`, `shouldReflect`." Happy to elaborate on this if needed.

Comment: @thejonymyster in the [tag:open-ended-function] challenge I was hoping for a smart solution using some transformation not listed. These transformations are actually what pops up in literature ([wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Essentially_different_solutions)) - your previous comment prompted me to research this closer. But if it isn't a case, you're right that [tag:decision-problem] may be better.

Comment: @Pandu thanks for help in the wording. Regarding the challenge idea, I think you're right that it may be overspecified.

Answer (score 2):

[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## N-element Rock Paper Scissors

Given an odd integer \$n>2\$, decide the winner for \$n\$-element Rock Paper Scissors.

#### What is \$n\$-element Rock Paper Scissors?

Rock Paper Scissors is a game in which two players choose between the elements Rock, Paper, and Scissors, and simultaneously reveal their selections. If one player chooses Rock, they will win against a player who chose Scissors, lose against a player who choses Paper, and tie a player who also chose Rock. It is a zero sum game, so a player losing means their opponent has won, and vice versa. Every element beats one element, loses to another, and ties with itself.

A common extension to this game is to add two aditional elements (most famously "Lizard" and "Spock"). In this extension, there are now 5 elements, so each element beats *two* elements, loses to *two* elements, but still ties only itself. We can generalize this cleanly to any odd number of elements \$n\$, in which each element will beat \$(n-1)/2\$ elements, lose to \$(n-1)/2\$ elements, and tie with itself.

#### Challenge specification

##### Program 1

This program should take an odd integer \$n>2\$ as input in any reasonable format decided by the solver, and output the Program 2 as defined below in terms of \$n\$. Alternatively, this program may instead take the Program 2's inputs along with \$n\$, and provide the Program 2's expected output instead.

This program is the one you will be scored on. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

##### Program 2

This program should take two elements \$A\$ and \$B\$ as input in any reasonable format decided by the solver, and consistently output either one of the following:

- Whether \$A\$ beats \$B\$, loses to \$B\$, or ties with \$B\$.
- The winner between \$A\$ and \$B\$, or in the case of a tie, some other distinct output.

Only \$n\$ possible inputs need to be handled by this program. Each possible element must consistently beat \$(n-1)/2\$ elements, lose to \$(n-1)/2\$ elements, and tie with itself. If some element \$a\$ beats an element \$b\$, element \$b\$ loses to element \$a\$. Which elements are allowed and which elements beat which etc. are to be decided by the solver. This must be consistent for each execution of Program 2 for the same \$n\$

#### Examples:

Your I/O may differ.

```
Format:
n (input to Program 1)
a b c d e (list of inputs accepted by Program 2, space delimited for all examples)
x y (inputs to Program 2, space delimited for all examples)
value (whether x wins, loses, or ties y)

3
r p s
r p
lose

3
r p s
r r
tie

3
r p s
r s
win

5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1
win

5
0 1 2 3 4
0 2
win

5
0 1 2 3 4
0 3
lose

5
0 1 2 3 4
0 4
lose

5
abcde bcdea cdeab deabc eabcd
bcdea cdeab
lose

5
abcde bcdea cdeab deabc eabcd
bcdea deabc
lose

5
abcde bcdea cdeab deabc eabcd
bcdea eabcd
win

5
abcde bcdea cdeab deabc eabcd
bcdea abcde
win

5
abcde bcdea cdeab deabc eabcd
bcdea bcdea
tie

13
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
g e
lose

13
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
g m
win

13
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
d h
win

13
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
h d
lose
```

## Meta

Everything clear? Any other examples needed? Maybe a worked out example?

Comment: info: i am currently working on a worked-out example including a visual aide, and also like in the process of getting a new job, so thats what is taking me so long on this lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Repeat Values In Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252442/repeat-values-in-array)

Comment: this is actually a builtin in jelly (`x`)

Answer (score 2):

## Abbreviate the inputted phrases

Given an ASCII string, replace all occurrences of " is ", " are ", " am ", and " have " with "'s ", "'re ", and "'ve " respectively. This must be done case insensitively.

### Examples

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| I am | I'm |
| She is | She's |
| The dog is | The dog's |
| I have a dog | I've a dog |
| I have been hurt | I've been hurt |
| Wadsfajsdfl have asdasd | Wadsfajsdfl've asdasd |
| So, is 6 am fare | So,'s 6'm fare |
| foo amxyz | foo amxyz |
| have I | have I |
| HAVE I | HAVE I |
| I HAVE | I've |
| I AM | I'm |
| I haven't | I'ven't |
| ambc xisz | ambc xisz |

Comment: What is the expected result for "So, is 6 am fare"?

Comment: I'll add it as a test case, one moment.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75582/golf-english-using-contractions) (this one is much simpler)

Comment: What's the winning criterion? What character set is expected in the input? What to do if the word to replace is at the beginning of string? How do we handle upper case? Please specify those the rules. Suggested test cases: "foo amxyz", "have I", "I HAVE", "I haven't", "ambc xisz".

Comment: Done! <filler text>

Comment: Personally, I think this challenge would be better if it wasn't a simple replacement challenge, and wouldn't replace things in the middle of words and after punctuation. For example: "So, is 6 am fare" -> "So, is 6'm fare", "foo amxyz" -> "foo amxyz"

Comment: Hmmm, that would make sense. I'll change the rules, then.

Answer (score 2):

[Make a Court Transcriber](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252927/make-a-court-transcriber)

Answer (score 2):

## Infinite Integer Derivative [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

We can consider the derivative of a integer sequence to simply be the difference between each element and the next:

```
1  5  8  13  2
 4  3  5  -11
```

Note this will produce a sequence one shorter than the original. We can repeat this process to find the second derivative:

```
-1 2 -16
```

And continue this process till there is one element left.

**Conjecture** A sequence of length `n` can be exactly represented by first element of each integer derivative. We call this the infinite integer derivative.

Example:

```
              [8   4  12   6  3]
8              [-4  8   -6  -3]
8 -4             [12 -14  3]
8 -4 12           [-26  11]
8 -4 12 -26          [37]
8 -4 12 -26 37
```

Example python code:

```py
f = lambda x:x and [x[0]]+f([x[i]-x[i-1] for i in range(1,len(x))])
```

Note there may be more efficient ways to compute values than this formula.

### Test cases

```py
{
    [1,2,3,4,5]:    [1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,2,1,2,1]:    [1,1,-2,4,8],
    [1,2,4,8,16]:   [1,1,1,1,1],
    [5,1,-1,0,6,3]: [5,-4,2,1,1,-17],
    []:             [],
    [12]:           [12],
    [5,5,5,5,5,4]:  [5,0,0,0,-1],
    [5,4]:          [5,-1]
}
```

Comment: [Related but closed.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/184951/9288)

Comment: While the pyramid shape is the same this is about a different combination of sides and the formula appears to be completely different.

Comment: I believe your example has an arithmetic error, it should be 
```
[8, 4, 12, 6, 3]
[-4, 8, -6, -3]
[12, -14, 3]
[-26, 17]
[43]
```

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't have `[]` as a valid input, since I don't think it adds anything in particular to the challenge and it might prevent some interesting approaches.

Comment: Very closely related: [binomial transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229772/78410), which is the same as this but with the sign flipped at odd indices (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform)).

Answer (score 2):

## [Partial Fractions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252993/partial-fractions)

Comment: I think that most of this challenge would involve the somewhat tedious task of parsing the input rather than actually making the partial fractions. Also, isn't the first testcase you gave using a factorised input (`(x+3)^2`)?

Comment: Suggested input format: two list of integers that represent the coefficients of the numerator and the denominator. Suggested output format: A list of pairs of lists of integers. For example: `([1, 4], [1, 6, 9]) -> [([1], [1, 3]), ([1], [1, 6, 9])]`.

Comment: @DialFrost `x^2+3` would be `[1,0,3]`.

Comment: @alephalpha fixed! Tysm, is there anything else that needs fixing?

Comment: @DialFrost Suggested tag: [tag:polynomials].

Answer (score 2):

## Prime factor power sorting

### Background

We will introduce a new way of writing numbers where the digits represent powers of primes starting with the largest prime factor of the number, and ending with the power of 2 in the prime factorization. As an example, 2 = 2<sup>1</sup>, so it would be written as `1`. Slightly more complicated, 3 = 3<sup>1</sup> * 2<sup>0</sup>, so it is written as `1 0`. Here's a few more:

```
6:     1 1
7: 1 0 0 0
8:       3
9:     2 0
10:  1 0 1
```

So the place value of the n'th "digit" is the n'th prime number, and the digit itself represents the power of that prime in the factorization of the number. 1 is encoded simply as   or `0` (the choice does not affect comparison).

### The Challenge

We can compare numbers in this form by first examining how many digits it has, and then breaking ties by comparing the digits themselves like normal. For instance, any power of 2 has only one digit, and so 2<sup>n</sup> < 3 for all n because 3's prime power representation has two digits. However, when numbers have the same length (meaning their highest prime factors are equal) we compare the lists of digits element-wise. Therefore 12 < 9 because 12th = `1 2` and 9 = `2 0`.

Your challenge is to write a function or program which takes as input a collection of distinct integers greater than or equal to 1, and outputs the same collection sorted this way in ascending order. This is code golf, so the score is the length of your solution in bytes.

### Examples:

I have written an example solution ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPbbtswDH3XV3ApBkid29pJVwxBvcd9wd6CwJAduVEqS54so8uGfntGSbZzabs8OCJ5dHhIke3ebY1eHA61NQ1URilROWl0B7JpjXWwETXvldvIypGAqXtdOWPUhKiatnCmeBZ7QhANsitaKxtBNVsSAFmDhjyHORgbTwvvBrDC9VbDT9sL4nGAGPx/2UolQF5fz@ExB72EKzBa7UELsQFnoNqK6hn61p@7X9ZhmkAX8nz2NDmkMcOU4wdXnYgo@JJDRi6ye9k1x7Ks/HOpOztTS9PEp9NFZdo9KtYnyiNDh9ZJ06jUjgFGj6XFuj4WPfCs5HoU638a7u5ykMESWM6IHipCqzUvIqRfrdHq5JOWtay4dugaO1DjI@xAarBcP2GpoY4EsgRuMjZpmp5wx6Y09aRrtx6dl1lCN8dQlHPL21boDT1eZmSACIWkJwTLD66mbAocH871rRI0All8wco0LbeC8iKBsgjKOZ5Q1/FtecGSExNhiLoar0K5ByX0k9vCi8RPSDIEZWc08A6cFKUV/FnYOCSIp5zBpzycymMTh8DjmX/Sf5ORqQcD8vv7yHEAyOm74y2O1OV/WDkSlm@4COmM6v2KY18Ub8oNB9033RI6XGaxod5IALc5Py42HfrD2EH85g02JYxZ4F7h7MwTWCRwn8DXdRKd82B@w8l6wBhaD2guhqiSnaNxALOImDP2JnSfIt/DO4EsTTGUpfOUMbImfqQHVX6wR4Gxcgw23BW@qMt6ZzC73Rmp6apzFpc@7Ib2FD6@jkOHa6AdrWd/T4jokIK9LuHMP3Z2ArDXGSOHfw)) which generates the following examples with the input and output separated by a colon:

```
1 2 3 4 5: 1 2 4 3 5
2 4 8 16 32 64 3: 2 4 8 16 32 64 3
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15: 1 3 9 5 15 7 11 13
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55: 48 54 40 45 50 42 49 44 55 52 51 46 41 43 47 53
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010 1011 1012 1013 1014 1015 1016 1017 1018 1019: 1000 1008 1001 1014 1012 1015 1007 1003 1005 1010 1017 1016 1002 1004 1011 1006 1018 1009 1013 1019
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Triangular honeycomb numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253418/78410)

Answer (score 2):

## [Box blur the string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253506/box-blur-the-string)

Comment: Don't forget to specify the scoring system, I'm assuming code golf, in which case you just need to stick a "This is [tag:code-golf], so shortest code in bytes wins."

Comment: tag suggestions: [tag:ascii-art], [tag:array] or maybe [tag:matrix] i think

Answer (score 2):

## [Conversions Galore!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/conversions-galore)

Answer (score 2):

### Generate the Sequence of Equivalence Relations ([OEIS A231428](https://oeis.org/A231428))

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences) [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-matrix)

#### Introduction

An [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) \$R\$ on a set \$S\$ is

- reflexive: \$ \forall a\in S: aRa\$
- symmetric: \$ \forall a,b \in S: aRb \leftrightarrow bRa \$
- transitive: \$ \forall a,b,c \in S: aRb \wedge bRc \rightarrow aRc \$

These relations can be represented as boolean matrices where:

- reflexive: the diagonal is all ones
- symmetric: the entries are symmetric over the diagonal (\$a_{ij}=a_{ji}\$)
- transitive: the matrix, when pairs of rows and the corresponding pairs of columns are suitably swapped, consists of entirely-1 and entirely-zero blocks, with the on-diagonal blocks entirely-1.

Here are a few such matrices:

```
1 0        1 1 0 0 0        1 0 1 0       can swap rows     1 1 0 0
0 1        1 1 0 0 0        0 1 0 1  -->  2&3, columns  --> 1 1 0 0
           0 0 1 1 1        1 0 1 0       2&3 to obtain:    0 0 1 1
           0 0 1 1 1        0 1 0 1                         0 0 1 1
           0 0 1 1 1
```

Making use of the reflexive and symmetric properties, we can encode such a matrix by concatenating the rows of its upper-right triangle, and converting from binary to decimal. (The example matrices encode as 0b0=0, 0b10 0000 0111=519, 0b01 0010=18, and 0b10 0001=33.)

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that outputs all equivalence relations in order (as encoded above). [Default sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) apply, so you can output an unbounded list, you can take an input \$n\$ and return the \$n^{th}\$ term, or you can take an input \$n\$ and return the first \$n\$ terms. [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) forbidden. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program wins.

For reference, the first 25 terms of this sequence are

```
0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 12, 16, 18, 25, 32, 33, 42, 52, 63, 64, 68, 80, 96, 116, 128, 130, 136, 160, 170
```

Here are example matrices which generate the first few terms of the sequence:

```
A: 1 0 0     
   0 1 0    0b000 -> 0    
   0 0 1     
          
B: 1 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0    0b00 0000 0001 -> 1    (also: 1 1 among others)
   0 0 1 1                                  1 1 
   0 0 1 1

C: 1 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 1 0 1    0b00 0000 0010 -> 2
   0 0 0 1 0
   0 0 1 0 1

D: 1 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 1 1 0    0b00 0000 0100 -> 4
   0 0 1 1 0
   0 0 0 0 1

E: 1 1 1
   1 1 1    0b111 -> 7
   1 1 1

F: 1 0 0 1
   0 1 0 0    0b00 1000 -> 8
   0 0 1 0
   1 0 0 1

G: 1 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 1
   0 0 1 1 0    0b00 0000 1100 -> 12
   0 0 1 1 0
   0 1 0 0 1
```

#### Sandbox notes

related: [Is This an Equivalence Relation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251626/103237), [Determine if a relation is transitive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100660/103237)

My first try, so please don't be shy about suggesting improvements, making edits, heckling... I can take it =)

Comment: While I think it's mostly clear, I think it would be helpful if you included the matrices for the first 2 or 3 values in the sequence. Additionally, the default [sequence] rules also allow answers to take \$n\$ as input and output the first \n\$ terms. I'd clarify that isn't allowed, if you intend to override the default. Other than that, looks like a well-written and interesting challenge!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks for the thoughts. On including the first few examples: would you suggest making that code-block one fairly-wide line of examples, or include a few lines of matrices. (I don't know what's easiest to scroll around for people.) On the second point, I didn't intend to override the default--I'll just remove mention of \$n\$ from the challenge section.

Comment: I think either a code block, or a few lines of mathjax, would both work fine, it's probably just a matter of preference

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## Number program police

This question is related to [Counting and so on](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233919/counting-and-so-on)

### Content

With some clever engineering, we now have program that can count like us.

But this is not enough. We are making a math society and society isn't as simple as counting.

There is always some blatant *number police* who calls you out if you makes a single bit of mistake. Without those *police* it will never be a complete society.

### Task

Make a program that identifies whether a `shape` is a `number shape`.

### shape

A shape is a Boolean matrix, here represented using spaces and #s:

```
 ########
 #   ####
 ########
```

(the above shape is also an example of valid Number shape which represents `0`)

### Number shape

Basic `Number shape`:

```
  #  ###  ###  # #  ###  ###  ###  ###  ###  ###
  #    #    #  # #  #    #      #  # #  # #  # #
  #  ###  ###  ###  ###  ###    #  ###  ###  # #
  #  #      #    #    #  # #    #  # #    #  # #
  #  ###  ###    #  ###  ###    #  ###    #  ###
```

A basic Number shape can be enlarged, twisted, be longer or shorter, while still being valid, as long as it Resembles the shape:

```
Is a Number shape of 9:
#####  ######  ###
##  #  #    #  # #
##  #  ######  ###
#####       #  ###
    #       #    #
    #       #    #
            #

Is not a Number shape of 9:

###   #####   ###  ####
# #   # #     # #  # ##
# #   ###     ###  ###
  #     #      #     #
        #      #     #
```

```
Acceptable reshape:

Original shape:

   ###               ####
   # #      widen    #  #
   ###     ------->  ####
     #                  #
     #                  #

           extend   ###       shorten   ###
           -------> # #   or            # #
                    ###                 ###
                      #                   #
                      #
                      #



          lengthen  ###
           -------> # #
                    # #
                    ###
                      #
                      #

     enlarge line   ###      ####      ####      ###           ###
           -------> ###  or  # ##  or  ## #  or  # #  but not  # # (this is
                    # #      ####      ####      ###           ###  not 9
                    ###        ##         #      ###           ###  but a 0)
                      #        ##         #        #           ###  
                      #
```

You can do 1 or more of those actions on the same digit for any amount of units, for example:

```
#####
#  ##
#  ##
#####
   ##
   ##
   ##
   ##
```

Is Widened, extended, enlarged, and lengthened.

The Basic Number shape (or smaller varient of it) should be obtained if you repeatedly remove one out of two consecutive identical rows or columns.

For digits that contain a hole in it (6, 8, 9, 0), the hole should exist for it to be valid (length, wide does not matter).

For U-shaped holes (2, 3, 4, 5, 6), those should have at least one empty byte that resembles a hole:

```
###  is done by shortening, and then enlarge line.
 ##  
###  Valid.
 ##
###
```

For numbers that have more than one digit, digits should have at least one spacing between them, and they should not be connected in any way:

```
#  ###
#    #
#  ###
#  #
   ###
is identified as 12
```

A `Number shape` can also start with 0:

```
### #
# # #
### #
```

### I/O

Basically follows the standard I/O rules:

The input can be request in any convenience format

For example, list the split with newline can be the input.

The output follows the standard output rule

### Testcase

Is `Number shape`: (`-` is to separate each testcase out)

```
###
# #
###
------------------
#####
#####
## ##
#####
#####
------------------
### 
# # #
### 
------------------
 ####
 #  #
 ####
 #  #
 ####
------------------
# # # # #
```

Is not `Number shape`:

```
 ##
  #
###
# 
###
------------------
#####
#####
## ##
#####
  ###
------------------
######
# #  #
# ####
# ##
######
------------------
#######
#   # #
### ###
# #   #
###   #
------------------
####
# ##
####
## #
####
------------------
###
  #
 ##
  #
###
```

### Rules

- No standard loopholes
- is `code golf` so shortest police is the best police.

### Meta

- Is the title good?
- Any tag that suits this question but not included?
- Is it clear?
- Extra suggestion would help me out a lot!

Comment: I suggest sticking to [standard decision-problem output rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info) (e.g. allowing truthy/falsy). Also, please add some test-cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [Counting Stripey Bracelets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254179/counting-stripey-bracelets)

Comment: I suggest adding an example (or examples) which will correspond to the bracelets on the image, which is used to explain the idea of stripes (e.g `(6,3,4)` and/or `(6,3,6)`).

Comment: Good call @pajonk, I've aligned a couple of the examples and highlighted which are where in the image.

Answer (score 2):

## Fastest approximate square root of a floating point number

[fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation)

---

In this challenge, you'll approximate the square root of a floating point number, using some basic arithmetic, bitwise, and control flow operators. Your score will take into account the number of operations your code performs, in addition to its accuracy.

**Background:**

(Expanation of how IEEE-754 double precision floats work)

**Opcodes:**

(A list of operations, including basic arithmetic, bitwise, and conditionals/jumps)

(Paradigm, probably either based on a finite number of registers or a stack, is yet to be decided)

**Task:**

Given a 64-bit floating point number, approximate its square root in the fewest number of operations possible. Your score is a sum of the scores for (around 100k) individual test cases, each of which is scored as the following, where \$n_{ops}\$ is the number of operations the program took to complete, \$x\$ is the input, and \$f(x)\$ is the program's output:

$$\frac{{n_{ops}}^2}{\max(\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}},\frac{\sqrt{x}}{f(x)})}$$

(Note that the actual \$\sqrt{x}\$ will be used for scoring, rather than the closest floating point value, meaning that even a maximally accurate submission would still be slightly penalized for inaccuracy)

Comment: The question of the fastest floating-point calculation of the square root has been coming up again and again for decades, but is hardly relevant anymore on modern architectures and standard libraries. I have a little doubt whether such a question still makes a lot of sense, since there are already excellent answers, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336291/fastest-way-to-get-square-root-in-float-value . Everyone who wants to win such a challenge has hardly any other option than to copy the already known methods.

Comment: @HugoPfoertner I disagree. This question will likely encourage answers which use just a few instructions total. Not having to be very accurate, at all, will allow for some really neat bitwise stuff.

Comment: In order for me to be able to imagine anything concrete under the problem statement, you would have to be a bit more specific as to what you want to allow under "basic arithmetic". Without division, for example, it gets tricky. Likewise, you would have to say if you have an instruction to get the exponent of the floating point number. Without such information it is difficult to decide whether this will be a worthwhile task.

Comment: @HugoPfoertner I'm thinking something like this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62332621#62332621

Comment: FYI you can use `\left` and `\right` to make the brackets the right size.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms It is a bit strange when reference is first made to IEEE-754 double precision floats, but then in the task no use is made of the division of the number into mantissa and exponent described there. If you deny direct access to the exponent, then most of the "neat bitwise stuff" mentioned is probably needed to get the exponent information anyway.

Comment: @HugoPfoertner All of the bitwise operations would act on the 64-bit integer representation of the float, not the float itself (just like in assembly/machine code). So to shift the mantissa for example, you could mask that, shift it, and xor the old sign and exponent back in. I considered adding operations which acted specifically on either the mantissa or exponent, but that seemed like it would make it too easy.

Answer (score 2):

## [Maximum average ord](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254224/114446)

Comment: `It may be rounded to any number of decimal places.` Can that number be zero (integer)? Can we floor or ceil instead of round?

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan - I'll say it must be 1 or more (I've edited that into the post). And, it must be rounded properly (e.g. 1.23 cannot be "rounded" to 1.3).

Answer (score 2):

## [Simple Boolean Algebra Calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254514/simple-boolean-algebra-calculator)

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but the current structure of the post makes it hard to tell what the program is supposed to do. Perhaps you could break down and explain one of the examples in full?

Comment: @Ginger Thanks for commenting! I added some explanations above.

Answer (score 2):

## [Transform a lattice polygon to minimum diameter by shearing](https://Transform%20a%20lattice%20polygon%20to%20minimum%20diameter%20by%20shearing)

Comment: The math formulas look... strange. Why not MathJax?

Comment: I hope it's better now. I have little practice in writing LaTeX, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: That'll do. Besides, you might want to align the testcases so that it'll be easier to comprehend the inputs and outputs

Comment: The alignment is done. Now the input has to handle spaces between the numbers correctly.

Comment: We generally [discourage cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/55372) and prefer to let answerers choose what's best for them ([within reason](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)).

Comment: @pajonk I don't think the proposed output format is cumbersome. I would just like to be able to directly interpret the results of the programs. If someone is unable to separate the coordinates with commas, for example, then the program is of little use to me.

Comment: You may ask to provide code to convert from golfiest representation to your output, but score only the main task. I suspect that in some languages the boilerplate code to handle specific I/O may be as long as the code to solve the task. This makes the challenge less interesting in my opinion. Also, I suggest rephrasing the winnning criteria, as now ("the shortest code able to solve all test cases wins") it is closer to [tag:test-battery] than [tag:code-golf] - in [tag:code-golf] we usually require the code to theoretically handle any case of the specified problem.

Comment: @pajonk Thanks for the suggestions! I have now tried to change the task description accordingly. I suppose that it goes without saying that all the specified tests must be passed.

Answer (score 2):

## Where are zeros? Self-describing sequence [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

### Background

> [A167519](http://oeis.org/A167519): Lexicographically earliest increasing sequence which lists the positions of the zero digits in the sequence.

```
3, 10, 11, 12, 11000, 11111, 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115, 11116, 11117, 11118, 11119,
11121, 11122, 11123, 11124, 11125, 11126, 11127, 11128, 11129, 11131, 11132, 11133,
11134, 11135, 11136, 11137, 11138, 11139, 11141, 11142, 11143, 11144, ...
```

If we list the digits, we get

```
3 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 4 ...
    ^             ^ ^ ^
```

The digits at index 3, 10, 11, 12, 11000, ... are zeros, and all the other digits are nonzero.

It looks a bit boring after a few terms. It becomes a bit more interesting if we consider the same sequence in smaller bases:

#### Base 5

```
(in base 10)
3, 5, 10, 11, 150, 156, 157, 158, 159, 161, ...

(in base 5)
3, 10, 20, 21, 1100, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1121, ...
```

Explanation:

1. The first term cannot be 1 (the first base-5 digit is 1, not 0) or 2 (the next number would have a leading zero), so it is 3.
2. The next term cannot be 4 (leading zero), so it must be `5 = 10(5)`. It satisfies the first term (3rd base-5 digit is 0).
3. The third term must have at least 2 digits and its 2nd digit is 0. The smallest number that satisfies this is `10 = 20(5)`.
4. Another 2-digit number can fit here without causing a leading zero. The smallest such number exceeding 10 is `11 = 21(5)`.
5. The next number cannot be 2-digit or 3-digit, so it must have 4 digits, giving `1100(5)`. We don't have any more zeros for a while, giving a series of zeroless numbers starting with `1111(5)`.

#### Base 4

```
(in base 10)
3, 8, 9, 80, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107,
109, 110, 113, 1344, 16448, 21824, 32833, 34133, 38229, 38230, 38231, ...

(in base 4)
3, 20, 21, 1100, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1131, 1132, 1133, 1211, 1212,
1213, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1231, 1232, 1301, 111000, 10001000, 11111000, 20001001,
20111111, 21111111, 21111112, 21111113, ...
```

1. The first term is 3 by the same logic.
2. The next term cannot be `10(4)` due to leading zero, and the next fitting number is `20(4)`.
3. The rest goes on by the "long-term logic". The next interesting part comes earlier than in higher bases, so I decided to include it here.

Starting here, the "long-term logic" refers to the following:

- If the last number has `k` digits, the next number will also have `k` digits unless such a number does not exist or it causes a leading zero in the next term.
- Otherwise, increase the number of digits until the next term won't have a leading zero, and fill the nonzero digits with 1.

#### Base 3

```
(in base 10)
4, 6, 10, 12, 19, 22, 24, 111, 121, 122, 124, 125, 130, 131, 133, 134, 148, 149,
151, 152, 157, 158, 160, 161, 202, 283, 1089, 6921, 6925, 9837, 13482, 13486,
16402, 16403, 16405, 16408, 16411, 16412, 16414, 16415, 16429, 16430, 16432,
16433, 16435, ...

(in base 3)
11, 20, 101, 110, 201, 211, 220, 11010, 11111, 11112, 11121, 11122, 11211, 11212,
11221, 11222, 12111, 12112, 12121, 12122, 12211, 12212, 12221, 12222, 21111,
101111, 1111100, 100111100, 100111111, 111111100, 200111100, 200111111, 211111111,
211111112, 211111121, 211111201, 211111211, 211111212, 211111221, 211111222,
211112111, 211112112, 211112121, 211112122, 211112201, ...
```

1. The first term *cannot* be 3 since it is `10(3)` but 2 is not in the sequence. Therefore, the first term is `4 = 11(3)`.
2. The sequence goes on with the long-term logic.

#### Base 2

```
(in base 10)
2, 4, 5, 7, 31, 63, 127, 191, 255, 511, 1021, 1023, 2047, 4095, 8191, 16383, 28671,
32767, ...

(in base 2)
10, 100, 101, 111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, 10111111, 11111111, 111111111,
1111111101, 1111111111, 11111111111, 111111111111, 1111111111111, 11111111111111,
110111111111111, 111111111111111, ...
```

Determining the initial terms here is particularly tricky.

1. The first term is `2 = 10(2)` because it satisfies the first zero position.
2. The next term cannot be 3, but `4 = 100(2)` works. This also fixes the next two terms `5 = 101(2)` and `7 = 111(2)`.
3. The next term should be at least 12, but:

   - 12 doesn't work because `<1>100` (`<x>` marks where 0 has to be)
   - 13 doesn't work because `1<1>01`
   - 14 doesn't work because `11<1>0`
   - 15 doesn't work because `111<1>`
     Therefore the number has at least 5 bits, the first 4 of which must be 1. Then the last bit cannot be 0 either (16 is not in the sequence), so it becomes `31 = 11111(2)`.
4. Now the rest follows the long-term logic, except that it continues to grow exponentially. This is because, for every number `k`, there is only one `k`-bit number that does not contain 0.

[Code used for handcrafting these sequences.](https://tio.run/##zVRBboMwELzzCt8IKqrsMdyal0Q5pCpRqVKIApXS11Ns7xrbiEo9NZfs7jA7xrsTrt/je9/paXo9DQ3EXhxyJfNSzL8UlA2KQ5AEmSJuCkd5VMj4UVKl5apeA4TI30kqP2aXYTQXbbtxN5QChTj3NzGIthN2CMfso2@75m3m5PmzyXcWL7LrzfQc7rbhbhqMVHue85e9uDTdznUWR89tn5Rlt6XlN93XZ3M7jQ0zXfd@PkrmvmtW9ekiWmSZeQ/tlmTvhnhH0mHuETGIMnPkaoOgBIyAEDAHzAFzQBywDlgHrAPWAeuAdcA6IB3E5vGvyO6TqyLaqqQry1WhlJdPCwQFgifL5JQfARdBD6Ke4BoIz0F4DsJzeDyuMIemltSJJfWGJfWDWLKyltSLI9ks0nuODUZRs73YVBQJ14RrwrVmq7HBKGq2F5uKIuGkA9LR/qMjvaWkz9WCw@H0H9v4cFTJlqqNLVUPsqV62RJ/Kf6yK1X5naWTqJNJ1BuTqP99EtP0Aw)

### Challenge

Given the base `n >= 2`, output the sequence generated by the definition of A167519 in base `n`.

[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O rules apply. You may choose one of the following:

- Given `n`, output the terms of the sequence indefinitely;
- Given `n` and a 0- or 1-based index `k`, output the `k`th term of the sequence `n`;
- Given `n` and a positive integer `k`, output the first `k` terms of the sequence `n`.

You may output the terms in base 10 or base `n`.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 2):

## Santa's Shortest Path Problem

1st-time trying to come up with a challenge. Please provide feedback if this is a nice challenge/if it's doable and/or if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for using the Sandbox! What do you mean by "readable format"? I suggest skipping the "readable" as it may be too vague. I also suggest relaxing the output to allow any kind of coordinates, not just letter+number. Finally, I suggest finishing the route at the last village as returning to A1 is unnecessary IMHO (but that just my preference).

Comment: @pajonk, thanks for the prompt response. I hope the edit makes for a more approachable challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## How much STAB do I get?

With the new Terastal mechanic in Pokémon Scarlet and Violet, moves can now get a variety of Same Type Attack Bonuses.

This bonus, known as STAB for short, varies depending on the type of the move and the Pokémon's type(s) (Pokémon can have multiple types) and Tera type, but also on whether the Pokémon has the Adaptability ability.

The rules are as follows:

- If the Pokémon hasn't been Terastallised:

  - If the move is not one of the Pokémon's types then the STAB is 1× (i.e. no bonus)
  - Otherwise if the Pokémon has the Adaptability ability then the STAB is 2×
  - Otherwise the STAB is 1.5×
- If the Pokémon has been Terastallised into a different type:

  - If the move is neither the Tera type or its regular types then the STAB is 1×
  - Otherwise if the move is the Tera type and the Pokémon has the Adaptability ability then the STAB is 2×
  - Otherwise the STAB is 1.5×
- If the Pokémon has been Terastallised into one of its regular types:

  - If the move is not one of the Pokémon's types then the STAB is 1×
  - Otherwise if the move is not the Tera type then the STAB is 1.5×
  - Otherwise if the Pokémon has the Adaptability ability then the STAB is 2.25×
  - Otherwise the STAB is 2×

As a table:

| Is Terastallised | Move has Tera type | Move has regular type | Adaptability | STAB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | No | No | No | 1× |
| No | No | No | Yes | 1× |
| No | No | Yes | No | 1.5× |
| No | No | Yes | Yes | 2× |
| No | Yes | No | No | 1× |
| No | Yes | No | Yes | 1× |
| No | Yes | Yes | No | 1.5× |
| No | Yes | Yes | Yes | 2× |
| Yes | No | No | No | 1× |
| Yes | No | No | Yes | 1× |
| Yes | No | Yes | No | 1.5× |
| Yes | No | Yes | Yes | 1.5× |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | 1.5× |
| Yes | Yes | No | Yes | 2× |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | No | 2× |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | 2.25× |

Your task is to write a program or function that, given a move's type, a Pokémon's Tera type and set of base type(s) as some kind of comparable value (e.g. type names as strings), and its Terastallisation and Adaptability states as a byte-sized flag, outputs the move's resulting STAB. Instead of a seprate Terastallisation flag you can also use a sentinel value for the Tera type to indicate that the Pokémon hasn't been Terastallised. You can optionally take an additional argument which is the set of types that are boosted by Adaptability.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 2):

## [Roll a painted cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257579/roll-a-painted-cube) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: May we map the directions to values `1-4` (or `0-3`)? May we map the colors to values `1-6` (or `0-5`)?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine also

Answer (score 2):

## But can it run Fibonacci?

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Cops will write a programming language interpreter (or transpiler or compiler) in 2048 bytes or less. It must be capable of a Fibonacci program which works until limited by integer sizes or some similar restriction (no finite look-up tables or similar, and a reasonable number of fibonacci numbers must be supposed, with `17711` being a reasonable minimum).

Robbers will try to find this fibonacci program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Approximate my Atomic Weight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255521/approximate-my-atomic-weight)

Comment: This would not be a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] because your output is not exact or a single string. I'd go with [tag:code-challenge] and [tag:approximation].

Comment: Also you don't need to have both `abs` and `²`, something squared can only ever be positive

Answer (score 2):

## Selection and Prediction

Your challenge: to select the strings `A` and `B` and predict others' selections in an [asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric)-style [koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth).

All entries should be Python 3.10ish
<sub>META: version? also possibly JS if I have time ._..</sub>

### Part 1: Selection

You are tasked with selecting the strings `A` and `B` as randomly as possible.
You are given the previous selections you have made and the guesses your 'opponent' has made.
Each input is a string of `A` and `B`. For example, `'ABBAB'` and `'ABABA'` may be arguments passed to your program.

Your program should output either of `A` or `B` [deterministically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm), meaning the same input should result in the same output. This means no calling `random.choice()` or similar, or using the date and time as seeds for a random number generator. <sub>META: maybe I should choose the first letter for them, since this constraint results in them always starting with the same letter</sub> You may also output a tuple `(letter_str, state)` and the state will be passed in as a keyword argument next round.

An example entry (this will compete):

##### Selector: AAAAAA, 3 bytes

Not much to say. This program loves the letter <kbd>A</kbd>

```python
def aaaaaa(selections, guesses):
    return "A"
```

### Part 2: Prediction

Your task is to predict the most likely move that your opponent will make. Same input, output and constraints as above.

Another example entry: (this will compete too)

##### Predictor: Anti-repeater, 3 bytes

Assumes you tend to repeat your previous selection.

```python
def anti_repeater(selections, guesses):
    # It's fine to modify the lists
    return selections.pop()
```

### Part 3: Scoring

Each *Selector* submission will go against each *Predictor* submission for a total of 110 rounds. They will select and predict for the first round, then select and predict again, and again, until all rounds have finished.

For each round correctly predicted (excluding the first 10 rounds, since they may be hard to predict) the *Predictor* submission wins 1 point. For each round incorrectly predicted (also excluding the first 10 rounds) the *Selector* submission wins 1 point.

The winners are the submissions with the most total points from all *Selector* and *Predictor* submissions. Since there are two winners no answer will be accepted.

If you type hint you get <s>0 extra points.</s> my respect!

### (Part 4: meta)

EDIT: added scoring

What do you call a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) where every cop goes against every robber and vice versa?

EDIT: Change 'key' to 'string' and fix up typo

EDIT: Some other stuff added

Comment: How will submissions be scored?

Comment: It's a KOTH - they go against each other

Comment: Who wins the KOTH though?

Comment: forgot that >_<
Added now

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `random.choice()`?

Comment: Thanks @UndoneStudios don't know how I missed that

Comment: Maybe you can allow seeded `random.choice()` as it still deterministic .

Answer (score 2):

## [Calculate my income tax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256003/114446)

Comment: If I earn £100,003, does my personal allowance go down by £1 or £1.50?

Comment: @pxeger Actually I'll change that. It's up to you which one you want.

Answer (score 2):

## [Find the Prime Signature](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256147/98937)

Comment: I find it a tad confusing that you group inputs with identical signatures together, using ", " but also use "," as thousands separator.

Comment: @Adám I've updated it to be consistent (removing thousands separator) with the Wikipedia list. I considered thousands separator with "; " as the list separator, but that looked worse (imo)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that outputting a `set` is not allowed as it has no defined order of elements?

Comment: @pajonk Correct. Not only is a `set` generally implemented without preserving insertion order, a `set` in computer science can only contain unique items; for example `6` has a prime signature of `{1, 1}` (in number theory set notation), but a `set` would only be able to store one of the `1`s

Answer (score 2):

## Find the first run of numbers summing to `n` [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Given as input a number `n` and a sequence of digits `0-9` (which may be taken as a string or a list), find the first contiguous subsequence of digits in the sequence that sums to `n` and output the start and end indexes. You may use zero- or one-based indexing. If no such subsequence exists, your program may output any *constant* value.

### Examples

These examples use zero-based indexing.

```
Input: 10 123456789
Output: 0 3
Input: 32 444444444
Output: 0 7
Input: 33 444444444
Output: No solutions
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first test case be 0 4?

Comment: @mousetail That would be the subsequence `12345`, which sums to 15.

Comment: My bad I assumed exclusive range

Answer (score 2):

## Estimate the world population, at 5 different levels of accuracy [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Your goal is, given a year between 1952 and 2020 to output the world population in that year. However, you must write 5 different expressions. Each program must contain the previous as a substring.

Your first program is 5 bytes, the second 10, then 20, 40 finally a program or function with a maximums size of 80 bytes. Each expression *must contain* the previous expression as a substring.

**For the purpose of this challenge, snippets that take input from global variables are allowed**, for all programs except the last. which must be either a complete program or a function.

### Scoring

For each year, your score is the product of the proportional square error. In other words:

$$\frac{(X_0 - V)^2 \cdot (X_1 - V)^2 \cdot (X_2 - V)^2 \cdot(X_3 - V)^2 \cdot (X_4 - V)^2}{V^{10}}$$

Where X<sub>n</sub> is the estimate your nth program outputs and V is the true population at that year. Your total score is sum of the score of each year.

Lower score is better.

### Example

> ### Python, Score \$7.503\cdot10^{59}\$
>
> Note the numbers here are absolute nonsense, I hope most submissions will have a score that can be written in the title without needing scientific notation
>
> 5 byte solution:
>
> ```
> 413e7
> ```
>
> 10 byte solution
>
> ```
> 413e7+x**2
> ```
>
> 20 byte solution
>
> ```
> 413e7+x**2.46*4.321
> ```
>
> 40 byte solution
>
> ```
> 0*413e7+x**2.46*4.321+x**3.718232*8.3e9
> ```
>
> 80 byte solution
>
> ```
> lambda x:0.010*413e7+x**2.46*4.321+x**3.718232*8.3e9+__import__("math").sin(x/2)
> ```

### Data

| Year | Population |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 7,794,798,739 |
| 2019 | 7,713,468,100 |
| 2018 | 7,631,091,040 |
| 2017 | 7,547,858,925 |
| 2016 | 7,464,022,049 |
| 2015 | 7,379,797,139 |
| 2014 | 7,295,290,765 |
| 2013 | 7,210,581,976 |
| 2012 | 7,125,828,059 |
| 2011 | 7,041,194,301 |
| 2010 | 6,956,823,603 |
| 2009 | 6,872,767,093 |
| 2008 | 6,789,088,686 |
| 2007 | 6,705,946,610 |
| 2006 | 6,623,517,833 |
| 2005 | 6,541,907,027 |
| 2004 | 6,461,159,389 |
| 2003 | 6,381,185,114 |
| 2002 | 6,301,773,188 |
| 2001 | 6,222,626,606 |
| 2000 | 6,143,493,823 |
| 1999 | 6,064,239,055 |
| 1998 | 5,984,793,942 |
| 1997 | 5,905,045,788 |
| 1996 | 5,824,891,951 |
| 1995 | 5,744,212,979 |
| 1994 | 5,663,150,427 |
| 1993 | 5,581,597,546 |
| 1992 | 5,498,919,809 |
| 1991 | 5,414,289,444 |
| 1990 | 5,327,231,061 |
| 1989 | 5,237,441,558 |
| 1988 | 5,145,426,008 |
| 1987 | 5,052,522,147 |
| 1986 | 4,960,567,912 |
| 1985 | 4,870,921,740 |
| 1984 | 4,784,011,621 |
| 1983 | 4,699,569,304 |
| 1982 | 4,617,386,542 |
| 1981 | 4,536,996,762 |
| 1980 | 4,458,003,514 |
| 1979 | 4,380,506,100 |
| 1978 | 4,304,533,501 |
| 1977 | 4,229,506,060 |
| 1976 | 4,154,666,864 |
| 1975 | 4,079,480,606 |
| 1974 | 4,003,794,172 |
| 1973 | 3,927,780,238 |
| 1972 | 3,851,650,245 |
| 1971 | 3,775,759,617 |
| 1970 | 3,700,437,046 |
| 1969 | 3,625,680,627 |
| 1968 | 3,551,599,127 |
| 1967 | 3,478,769,962 |
| 1966 | 3,407,922,630 |
| 1965 | 3,339,583,597 |
| 1964 | 3,273,978,338 |
| 1963 | 3,211,001,009 |
| 1962 | 3,150,420,795 |
| 1961 | 3,091,843,507 |
| 1960 | 3,034,949,748 |
| 1959 | 2,979,576,185 |
| 1958 | 2,925,686,705 |
| 1957 | 2,873,306,090 |
| 1956 | 2,822,443,282 |
| 1955 | 2,773,019,936 |
| 1954 | 2,724,846,741 |
| 1953 | 2,677,608,960 |
| 1952 | 2,630,861,562 |

In JSON format:

```json
{2020: 7794798739, 2019: 7713468100, 2018: 7631091040, 2017: 7547858925, 2016: 7464022049, 2015: 7379797139, 2014: 7295290765, 2013: 7210581976, 2012: 7125828059, 2011: 7041194301, 2010: 6956823603, 2009: 6872767093, 2008: 6789088686, 2007: 6705946610, 2006: 6623517833, 2005: 6541907027, 2004: 6461159389, 2003: 6381185114, 2002: 6301773188, 2001: 6222626606, 2000: 6143493823, 1999: 6064239055, 1998: 5984793942, 1997: 5905045788, 1996: 5824891951, 1995: 5744212979, 1994: 5663150427, 1993: 5581597546, 1992: 5498919809, 1991: 5414289444, 1990: 5327231061, 1989: 5237441558, 1988: 5145426008, 1987: 5052522147, 1986: 4960567912, 1985: 4870921740, 1984: 4784011621, 1983: 4699569304, 1982: 4617386542, 1981: 4536996762, 1980: 4458003514, 1979: 4380506100, 1978: 4304533501, 1977: 4229506060, 1976: 4154666864, 1975: 4079480606, 1974: 4003794172, 1973: 3927780238, 1972: 3851650245, 1971: 3775759617, 1970: 3700437046, 1969: 3625680627, 1968: 3551599127, 1967: 3478769962, 1966: 3407922630, 1965: 3339583597, 1964: 3273978338, 1963: 3211001009, 1962: 3150420795, 1961: 3091843507, 1960: 3034949748, 1959: 2979576185, 1958: 2925686705, 1957: 2873306090, 1956: 2822443282, 1955: 2773019936, 1954: 2724846741, 1953: 2677608960, 1952: 2630861562}
```

Comment: Just some nitpicking: you say 1951 in the question but only supply data back to 1952. Also I believe your 5 byte solution was meant to be `413e9`. Also it can be nice to provide a scoring script/link in some common language, not necessary of course.

Comment: 413e7 is correct, that comes out to 4,130,000,000. Note the lack of a decimal point in 413

Comment: Oh, I meant because that's what it is in the next four. Something needs to change for it to adhere to the substring rule.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

## [Print the notes of an increasing octave-repeating scale.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256924/108879)

Comment: Maybe talk some about half steps?

Answer (score 2):

## Cheat at Chess [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

Inspired by a meme my brother showed me that I cannot find anymore, that looked something like this with the caption "White to play, mate in one:"

[image]

The image shows the white rook going over several pieces to end up putting the black king in checkmate (`Rxh8`). Of course this is not a legal move, but it shows a misunderstanding of chess that I thought could make a fun code challenge.

### Task

Given a chess board as input, output the move that puts the king in check, using [algebraic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_%28chess%29).

The move must follow the movement rules for a chess piece, but can ignore any pieces standing in its way.

Input format: string matrix or multiline string, each element either empty (empty string, empty matrix element, whatever makes sense) or with a letter - `K`: King, `Q`: Queen, `R`: Rook, `B`: Bishop, `N`: Knight, or `P`: Pawn, uppercase for white and lowercase for black.

The input will always be a board that has a valid solution for this. If there are multiple possible solutions, choose any of them.

### Test cases:

```
r n b - k - - r
p p - p p p - p
- q p - - n p b
- - - - - - - -
- P - - - - - -    -> Rxh8
- - P P - - - -
P Q - - P P P P
R N B - K B N R

More test cases whenever I have time to make them.
```

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Sandboxing

- Should the task be "find the move that causes checkmate" instead of just check? I feel like this might make golfing too difficult though.
- I haven't had time to work on an implementation for solving this yet, so not sure how hard this will be.
- Any suggested test cases?

Comment: In the example you gave, the king is in check, it's not checkmate because the knight and bishop can block

Comment: @c-- Sorry, I suck at chess haha. That's why I need to cheat >.< I'll edit the example. The challenge does say to put the king in check, not checkmate though.

Comment: can ignore any pieces standing in its way. What about the last position(dst)?

Comment: Won't F1-B5 is another way to check?

Comment: I don't have time to finish this right now, I'll most likely come back to it in a few days.

Comment: Can I cheat to capture king?

Comment: Note that this cheat method isn't actually cheating - it's what chess anarchists like myself call the [Siberian swipe](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/101mir9/true_story_my_friend_in_kindergarten_zach/). Note that it can only be performed if the h file pawn hasn't been moved and if the h file rook hasn't been moved as well.

Comment: @lyxal that was the meme I was thinking of haha. I’ll mention it in the challenge, but I already wrote the challenge so I don’t think I’m going to change it

Answer (score 2):

## Enable 2char-JsFuck

Write some javascript code that allow using only 2 characters to execute all javascript code.

As I can tell, these are possible chosen set:

```
f`   [a-zA-Z$_]`
f;   [a-zA-Z$_][;,\n]
f.   [a-zA-Z$_]\.
[]   \[\]
```

Obviously, [the first one](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbYViO6IlbT1q7CXqNY29apNC0ttQgopJeTmpdekhGrqZOmaZValpijUaz5Py0hjXyQQInmQWXJQFpIdw@OgFClk22kWjMsA2EALCTeImJUUs/ZgzTZjdpGkYU0c9Kwr9qGa/IhwhYqFzwJCQn/AQ) is lot easier than the other few. Therefore, different set are not scored together.

Shortest code in each (environment,chosen set) wins.

## Sandbox Notes

- Any other sets? (not counting `g+` or other variable name)
- Why I remember I've sandboxed this idea?

Comment: Is the code we write a function or a full program? Can we choose to insert the two-char JSFuck at an arbitrary point of our code, or does it have to be at the end?

Comment: @Jacob Full program(actually snippet). Must be at the end otherwise it turns into binary converting

Answer (score 2):

## [Split some points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257870/split-some-points)

Answer (score 2):

## Output a random value from the last 16 values outputted [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Output the numbers 1-16 (or any other set of 16 distinct items). Then, repeatedly, output a random value chosen uniformly from the last 16 items outputted.

After the same item is printed 16 times in a row or more, halt.

Answer (score 2):

## [Make a Custom Bayer Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259633)

Comment: I think this part "successive numbers are as distant from each other as possible" needs more precise definition, as it's the main part of the challenge, as I get it. Also, as the input will be only 2,4,8 or 16, there is possibility that some approaches will just hardcode the outputs (no judgment, maybe it's intended).

Comment: @pajonk I will try to make that part more clear. Yes, there is the option of hardcoding the output, but I would expect that in most programming languages that would not be the shortest possible answer.

Comment: Is [0 3;2 1] valid?

Comment: @l4m2 As long as your output format stays consitent with orher inputs, yes.

Comment: It's not format, it's order when tie distance

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, that is allowed (the third rule).

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid the hole [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

[image: xkcd]

Given a continuous black-box function as a input, output a different continuous, differentiable function that never enters the box \$ 1.5 \leq x \leq 2 \wedge 1 \leq y \leq 1.5 \$. Your output must exactly match the input function when \$ x \leq 0 \vee 3 \leq x \$.

The output must be continuous. You may assume the input function is continous, and defined over all \$ \mathbb{R} \$. The function you output must also be defined over all \$ \mathbb{R} \$. Both functions must also be differentiable, meaning their derivative is defined everywhere.

You may optionally take the derivative of the input function as a second input.

You may assume your languages float type has infinite precision and all operations on it are exact.

Comment: An issue you are going to run into is that it's basically impossible (mathematically impossible not just really hard) to anything non-trivial with arbitrary real numbers. For example it is very easily undecidable whether the input even passes through the box. This is because an arbitrary real number takes up an infinite amount of memory, so any program that deals with them has to be able to treat them like streams of digits.

Comment: Yes, so for the width of the box the output of the original function would need to be entirely ignored, as like you say you don't know about any weired outlier that could happen in that area. In the space around the edges of the box, where this doesn't really matter, you would need to create some kind of interpolation function.

Comment: There is actually a really simple solution of just creating 2 cubic beziers around the edges of each box

Comment: I'm not sure if that "simple" solution is actually possible, for two reasons 1) Doing even basic math with arbitrary reals tends to be undecidable (addition is undecidable for example) 2) determining the derivative of a black box function is like super impossible, even with some pretty hefty assumptions.

Comment: I agree. This might be do-able if you limit it from a black-box function to a Polynomial with known values instead, although that may make it trivial

Comment: @WheatWizard that's why you can take the derivative as a second input

Comment: Also your solution just needs to theoretically work, ignoring numerical limits like always

Comment: Hole on your picture displaces with your word

Comment: @l4m2 sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

## [Time to shortest transposition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257631/time-to-shortest-transposition)

Comment: Is the answer `13:14`?

Comment: Why 14:21 not 413?

Comment: Once you fix that, suggested test case: `23:41 -> Nil`

Comment: 413 is not a valid 24-hour string. Note that when you shift around the numbers, you must pick the time string that comes *after* the input and is a valid 24-hour string

Comment: In this case, the transpositions are `12:41`, `11:24`, `11:42`, and `14:12`. Since all of these come before `14:21` , they cannot be picked.

Comment: So the time must be in the same day?

Comment: Technically, yes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Generate an emoticon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257683/generate-an-emoticon)

Answer (score 2):

## [Print all pandigital numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257752/print-all-pandigital-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ptolemy's table of chords](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257712/ptolemys-table-of-chords)

Comment: Suggested tag: [kolmogorov-complexity](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Answer (score 2):

## [Primes with Distinct Prime Digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258299/primes-with-distinct-prime-digits)

Comment: This challenge seems a bit boring, also please use the default [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) rules

Comment: @Jacob I thought I did follow the default sequence rules. Also, could you clarify what exactly makes the challenge boring?

Comment: The default sequence rules state that the submission may either output the nth term, the first n terms, or the entire sequence. I changed my mind about the challenge being boring, there are likely a few interesting ways to solve this

Comment: @Jacob Oh, I see, I misread the sequence page; it says the answers may use "one of the following", not "any of the following", so I got confused. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Is infinite loop allowed if choosing to output whole sequence, like other [tag:sequence]?

Comment: @l4m2 it's not an infinite sequence, though. Could you elaborate on what would be printed in an infinite loop?

Comment: Print nothing lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Generate a permutation from the high-water marks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258469/generate-a-permutation-from-the-high-water-marks)

Answer (score 2):

## All languages have their strengths, right? (Cops' thread) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

*This is the cops' thread of a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. The robbers' thread can be found [here] (**sandbox note**: will add the link when posting)*

The main idea of this challenge is whether there are languages which are always better than some other ones for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

As a cop, you will choose two languages, and claim that one of them (let's call it A) will always be better for code golf than the other (let's call it B). You post starts as uncracked.

Robbers have two avenues to crack your post:

- If they think your claim is wrong, they can crack it by giving a code golf task and a solution to it in B.
- If they think your claim is right, they can crack it by proving it.

If your post was cracked by a counterexample, you can counter the crack by giving a solution in A which is shorter than the given solution in B. This invalidates their crack, and makes your post uncracked once again. Robbers can now attempt to crack it again.

If your post was cracked by a proof you can't counter it (assuming the proof is correct).

### Scoring

Each cop gains 1 point for every uncracked post, and loses 1 point for every cracked post. The goal is to get as many points as possible.

### Rules

- Both languages must be freely available.
- Your claim must not be implied by [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) from existing uncracked posts.
- The robbers' tasks must disallow all [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), and allow all [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- The robbers' tasks must only have textual I/O.

## All languages have their strengths, right? (Robbers' thread) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

*This is the robbers' thread of a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. The cops' thread can be found [here] (**sandbox note**: will add the link when posting)*

The main idea of this challenge is whether there are languages which are always better than some other ones for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

As a robber, you have two ways to crack a claim:

- If you think the claim is wrong, you can crack it by giving a code golf task and a solution to it in the language the claim states is worse.

  - This crack can be countered by the cop finding a shorter solution in the language they claim is better.
- If you think the claim is right, you can crack it by proving it.

  - This crack can't be countered as long as the proof is correct.

### Scoring

Each robber gains 1 point for every uncountered robbers post, and loses 1 point for every countered robbers post. The goal is to get as many points as possible.

### Rules

- Your task must disallow all [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), and allow all [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- You task can only use textual I/O.

## Sandbox Questions

Does this format, where a cop claims something, a robber tries to refute/prove it, and the cop tries to defend it, seem interesting? Is it on-topic? What tags are appropriate? I haven't seen it before.

How should I disallow some types of builtins? I want to avoid the challenge turning to "find a builtin the other language doesn't have". In particular, if `eval` is allowed then the challenge of "Evaluate this language" will almost always be a universal robbers solution. However, I'm not sure how those builtins can be classified.

How should I prevent "output this specific error string" as a universal robbers solution?

Comment: I feel this might be too easy when considering languages that are very verbose but also have a very limited set of builtin like shakesphere. I'd suggest cops would need to have a challenge in mind that would crack it, to ensure it's actually possible, then reveal it after some time

Comment: @mousetail I thought about that, but for a hard challenge the solution for the problem in the two languages will be close in length, so it's quite possible the cop will miss some optimization which turns their proposed counterexample false. Additionally, this changes the challenge from finding pairs of languages with one strictly better to finding pairs of languages with very similar code-golf performances, which while an interesting challenge isn't what I want. I'd prefer to prevent trivial submissions in some other way, for example by allowing a proof of the cop's claim as a crack.

Answer (score 2):

## Convert imperative code to functional

### The imperative language

We'll consider 2 very simple languages, first a imperative one. The imperative language is a list of statements. Statements can be one of these 4 expressions:

```
[literal] // a literal
[variable] // a variable
([expression] # [expression]) // Some arbitrary operator
([expression] $ [expression]) // Some different arbitrary operator
```

Or one of these 3 statements:

```
[variable] = [expression] // assignment
while [expression] { [statement]* } // looping
if [expression] { [statement] } // condition
```

The last line is guaranteed to be a expression and it's value is the output of the entire program.

Note: Syntax isn't important here. You can take input as any arbitrary tree like structure. There is also no fixed format for variables, you can use any arbitrary infinite series to represent variables, and the same for literals. As long as all 6 values are distinct, you are good to go.

For example, take this code:

```
a=(5 # 2)
a=(a $ 7)
8 # a
```

This program would output `8`. You could represent this like this:

```
[
    {op:'=', left:0, right:{op:'#',left:5,right:2},
    {op:'=', left:0, right:{op:'$',left:{op:'var',var:0},right:7},
    {op:'#',left:8,right:{op:'var',var:0}}
]
```

Or even more concisely `[[4,0,[2,[0,5],[0,2]]],[4,0,[3,[1,0],[0,7]]],[2,[0,8],[1,0]]]`. Where the first number represents the index of the expression type and the rest the arguments.

The operators are guarenteed to be saf

### The functional language

The functional language has the following builtins:

```
[literal]         // a literal
[variable]        // a variable
(# [expr] [expr]) // one arbitrary operation, you don't need to worry about what it does
($ [expr] [expr]) // another arbitrary operation
(? [expr] [expr] [expr]) // if expression is truthy, return the first expression, otherwise the second
(lambda [variable]* [expr]) // define a function
([expr] [expr]*) // call a function with the given arguments
```

Again, you can use any built in tree-like structure to represent this, and use any data type with a potentially infinite number of items to represent variables and literals.

### Your task

Your task is to convert some code in the imperative language to the functional equivalent. For example:

```
a=12
b=15
if b # a {
   b = b $ 12
}
c=(a # 12) $ (a # 18)
while a $ (a # b) {
    a = a # (c $ b)
}
a
```

Could be converted to:

```
(
   (lambda a:
       (lambda b:
           (lambda b:
                (lambda c:
                    (lambda y:
                        (
                            y,
                            lambda q: (
                                  lambda a: (
                                       lambda a: a,
                                       (? ($ a ($ a b)) (q (# a ($ c b)))) a)
                                  )
                            ), a)
                        )
                    ),
                    lambda a: (a a)
                ),
                ($ (# a 12) (# b 18))
           ),
           ((? (# b a) ($ b 12) b)
       ),
       15
   )),
   12
)
```

This is code golf, shortest code wins. Size of the output is irrelevant, specifically you can just repeat the y combinator every loop.

Comment: Could you explain in the challenge how to convert imperative to functional? In addition, a worked out simple example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Generate a Random Integer

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Your task is to create a program or function that outputs an integer from \$-\infty\$ to \$+\infty\$ non-deterministically (the output will not always be the same result). Each integer should have a nonzero chance of being outputted.

### Rules

- Please explain what your code does to confirm that it can produce any integer.
- For the purpose of this challenge, you may ignore your language's number limits for storing an arbitrarily large/small number.
- Output should be in decimal form.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: How does "you may ignore number limits" interact with a builtin to produce a random value in the range [INT_MIN, INT_MAX]?

Comment: @Bbrk24 What I mean is that you would be able to store an arbitrarily large number into a variable or other data structure.

Comment: [related, but with stricter probability requirements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42786/78850)

Answer (score 2):

Idea:

> Given a polyomino shape figure out the minimum number of cuts required to fill it with a herring-bone pattern of 2×1 tiles.

Gylda is a contractor who installs decks. She receives the deck plan from an architect who always chooses it to be shaped as a polyomino, that is a single connected piece cut from a square grid. The deck surface is manufactured in 2×1 rectangular tiles. Gylda installs the tiles in a [herringbone pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herringbone_pattern) because it looks nice, and is stable.  However not all shapes can be made perfectly with a herringbone pattern, sometimes Gylda is forced to cut a tile in half. Sometimes Gylda is forced to cut a lot of tiles in half.  However how many cuts are needed, depends on exactly where the pattern is placed relative to the boundaries of the deck.

Now Gylda wants to minimize the number of cuts she has to make so she wants a computer program which will take a deck shape and will tell her the minimum number of cuts required.  This is the number of cuts, *not* the number of half pieces used in the final construction.  Each cut produces two 1×1 pieces which can both be used.

There is one catch.  If a herringbone pattern would produce a layout where two half pieces are adjacent by an edge, Gylda will instead place a single 2×1 tile, even though it breaks the herringbone pattern.  For
example in the following layout:

```
 ====||
 ||====
 ||||==
```

There are two half pieces in the bottom right so instead we would lay out a single whole piece:

```
====||
||====
||====
```

This means the 3×3 square polyomino only requires 1 cut, not 2.

Gylda wants the program to take this special rule into account.

### Task

Take a polyomino as input in any reasonable format.  Output the minimum number of cuts Gylda needs to install that deck.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could define a herringbone pattern, and highlight the tiles in the example.

Comment: @CommandMaster Yeah, this challenge is unfinished right now, so it's missing a deal of the specification.

Answer (score 2):

### Enumeration of free polyominoes

## [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259751/enumeration-of-free-polyominoes)

Comment: What makes a polyomino "free"?

Comment: What is a "rigid transformation"?  Is it an isometry, an orientation preserving isometry, a translation, something else ...?

Comment: @Wheat Wizard hope it's more clear now

Comment: I suggest listing drawings/ascii art of the polyominoes for the first few n.

Answer (score 2):

## Isolate the binary signals

There are `n` binary signals, with intervals of `1` through `n`. For example, for `n=3` the lists could be `[1], [0, 1], [1, 0, 1]`. Each list represents a repeating pattern. So `[0,1]` is really `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...]`

The signals all start at the same time, but they are sent over the same channel. So you only know the sum of all the signals at a given time.

Given a list of length at least `LCM(1..n)` representing the sum of the values at each item of each signal.

If there are multiple possible options, you may output any of them.

### Test Cases

| List | n | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2]` | 3 | `[1], [0,1], [1,0,1]` |
| `[2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3]` | 4 | `[[1], [0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]` |

Comment: Is `n` part of the input? Or can you output any valid `n` as long as `LCM(1..n)` isn't greater than the input length?

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw the GKMS aperiodic tile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259390/110698)

Answer (score 2):

## [Play Rock Paper Scissors 25](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259618/play-rock-paper-scissors-25)

Answer (score 2):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259696/doors-and-guards)

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me which doors are opened by which guards. I see the example of "i, 2, i..." but that doesn't form a clear pattern to me and I'm not sure why i is listed twice.

Comment: @Bbrk24  Yes, make it more clear!

Answer (score 2):

## [Shortest Path Around Obstacle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/260159/113573)

Answer (score 2):

## [The number of solutions to Hertzsprung's Problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260266/the-number-of-solutions-to-hertzsprungs-problem)

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Answer (score 2):

## Generate a random finite floating-point number

Your challenge is to write a program or function that when invoked outputs a [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) IEEE `float32` value.

- Any particular floating point value may not have more than a chance of `1` in `1,000,000,000` of being output. (There are `4,278,190,079` possible different outputs so this should not be too onerous a restriction.)
- You may convert the `float32` value to double precision or a reasonable string format, but e.g. `-0` and `0.0` count as the same float value, and JavaScript's `Math.random` would not be acceptable as it can only generate a few million different `float32` values - indeed the number of different values it generates that truncate to the same `float32` value is greater than the number of different resulting `float32` values.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: Are nan and +-inf float values?

Comment: @AndrovT Should I have repeated the word `finite`?

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Adjacent Items Sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/261433/91213)

Answer (score 2):

## Find the Geometric Mean of a set of Numbers

### Introduction

There isn't a geometric mean challenge here yet so I decided to post one.

### Challenge

Calculate the geometric mean of a set of numbers without using a built in function for it because that's *boring*.

- [See here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input and output methods.
- Input should be some sort of set of numbers (either as a list/array passed to a function or a list/array built by the program from user inputs).
- You do not need to cope with negative numbers.

The winner will be determined by the shortest (functional) code length in bytes, in the case of 2 answers having the same number of bytes then the winner will be determined by score.

### Example Input and Output

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| [2,2,2] | 2.00 or 2 |
| [1,2,3] | 1.82 |
| [0,5,4,7] | 0.00 or 0 |
| [8,5,4,7] | 0.79 |
| [1.7,2,0.3] | 1.00 or 1 |
| [3,8] | 4.9 or 4.90 |
| [12,21] | 15.87 |
| [0.5] | 0.5, or 0.50 |
| [3,9,2,5,7] | 4.52 |

#### Ungolfed [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ys0cogwkdo) example program:

```
f\left(l\right)=\sqrt[\operatorname{length}\left(l\right)]{\prod_{i=1}^{\operatorname{length}\left(l\right)}l\left[i\right]}
```

Comment: Consider defining what the geometric mean is for anyone unfamiliar

Comment: Banning Builtins is hard to enforce, I'd recommend allowing them, but encouraging non-builtin solutions to be included aswell.

Comment: I mean like, you'ren't allowed to just go 


def f(x):

    return geomean(x)

Comment: @emirps I'm not the OP but: To take the geometric mean of \$n\$ numbers, you multiply them all together, then raise this to the \$\frac1n\$th power, or take the \$n\$th root.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/182460/31625), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37217/31625). In addition to saying again that banning something as vague as a "built in function" is a bad idea, breaking ties by (vote?) score doesn't sound like it is a great idea. Ties are usually broken by earlier posting, but honestly determining the "winner" is not too important - the rules about scoring exist to be able to say if a score is better than another. Adding this score rule will add a weird ambiguity to what makes a submission good.

Answer (score 2):

## Sort int64 with float64 values

Your challenge is to create the following total ordering of int64 and float64 values:

- Apart from `-0.0` which sorts before `0.0`, two values of the same type sort according to which one is less than the other.
- Where two values of different types are exactly equal, the float64 sorts before the int64 if negative or after if positive. Note that `-0.0` counts as a negative float64 and `0.0` counts as a positive float64, and the int64 `0` compares between the two.
- int64 values that fall between the representations of two float64 values must sort between those two values. Similarly, float64 values that have fractional parts must sort between the nearest two integer values, although the previous rule allows you to simply truncate the float64 value towards zero to compare it to an int64 value.

Here are some int64 and float64 values in the correct order:

```
-9223372036854775808.0
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775807
-9223372036854774786
-9223372036854774785
-9223372036854774784.0
-9223372036854774784
-9223372036854774783
-9007199254740994.0
-9007199254740994
-9007199254740993
-9007199254740992.0
-9007199254740992
-4503599627370496.0
-4503599627370496
-4503599627370495.5
-4503599627370495.0
-4503599627370495
-4503599627370494.5
-1.5
-1.0
-1
-0.5
-0.0
0
0.0
0.5
1
1.0
1.5
4503599627370494.5
4503599627370495
4503599627370495.0
4503599627370495.5
4503599627370496
4503599627370496.0
9007199254740992
9007199254740992.0
9007199254740993
9007199254740994
9007199254740994.0
9223372036854774783
9223372036854774784
9223372036854774784.0
9223372036854774785
9223372036854774786
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808.0
```

Your code can either implement a sort function for a list of elements or it can be a comparator for use with your language's built-in sort function or some other suitable way of indicating the sort ordering.

You can earn brownie points for supporting nonfinite float64 values and arbitrary precision integers.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Answer (score 2):

## Create an equation for a convex polygon

It turns out that it's possible to create an equation for any convex polygon. Here is a simple example:

$$ \sqrt { 1 - x } \sqrt { 1 - y } \sqrt { x + y } = 0 $$

I don't know how to create a link to a graph, but I was able to use the graphing calculator at https://www.mathway.com/Graph to draw this equation by pasting the text `\sqrt { 1 - x } \sqrt { 1 - y } \sqrt { x + y } = 0` into its equation box. As you can see the result is a simple triangle, but it's possible to extend this idea to any convex polygon.

Please write a program or function that will take a list of points representing the vertices of a convex polygon and output an equation for that polygon in an acceptable format, typically TeX, but other formats would be acceptable if you can find a resource that will draw the polygon.

You can make reasonable assumptions regarding the input e.g. you can require the first point to be the one with the highest y-coordinate and the remaining points to follow the polygon in a clockwise direction.

Examples:

```
(-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1) => \sqrt { 1 - x } \sqrt { 1 - y } \sqrt { x + y } = 0
(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0) => \sqrt{1+x+y}\sqrt{1+x-y}\sqrt{1-x-y}\sqrt{1-x+y}=0
```

(I tried to write some more complex examples but even Mathway's calculator gave up at that point.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 2):

## Complexity of a binary matrix

This is a \$4\times 4\$ binary matrix:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

A row-add operation takes one row and adds it to another one where addition is done mod 2. For example adding the second row to the third would give the following matrix:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

It's possible to add a row to itself. This is the same as zeroing that row.

## Task

Given a \$n\times n\$ binary matrix your task is to figure out how many row-addition steps it would take to get to that matrix starting from the identity matrix. I call this the "complexity" of the matrix.

For example if we were given the following matrix as input

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Then your program would output \$5\$ since there's no shorter sequence than the following:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
1\leftarrow 2
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
2\leftarrow 1
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
1\leftarrow 2
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
1\leftarrow 3
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
3\leftarrow 3
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

It's is always possible to get to any matrix from the identity matrix (proof left as an exercise to the reader)

## Scoring

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code). I'll be running submissions on a Ryzen 1800X limited to 16GB of RAM (using ulimit).

Your code will take as input an infinite stream of matrices over stdin. A matrix is encoded as its size followed by the rows of the matrix. The input starts with 10 matrices of size 3 followed by 10 of size 4 and so on.

You must output (in order) to stdin the complexities of the matrices.

See [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3OzNzC_KLShSKEvNS8nO5uPIUbBWMucozMnNSFUKKSlOtuDjT8osU4hUy80Bq0lM1DA00gYKcBUWZeSUaeZpAJpqCPLA8VIEWxGC95Iz8zOTUYo1oAx3DWB2FbNs8TZ3i1AJbJSWgCXnatgqGEAdB3QVzHwA) code for an example input. I'll use this code to generate the input (but using a secret seed).

I will run each submission for 5 minutes. The submission that manages to process the most matrices will win. Ties will be resolved by the time it took to output the last matrix.

TODO: add test inputs.

## Bonus points

In case two submissions are tied to the nanosecond I might use these as a tiebreaker :D

Find a block diagonal matrix whose complexity is less than the sum of the complexities of the blocks on the diagonal.

Is there a block matrix whose complexity is less than one of the blocks on the diagonal?

Comment: So row addition is just XOR?

Comment: @mousetail yep!

Answer (score 2):

## [How powerful must this e approximation be?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261112/how-powerful-must-this-e-approximation-be)

Answer (score 2):

## Generate the SMKG aperiodic tiling

### Task

Smith, Myers, Kaplan and Goodman-Strauss [discovered](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10798) the first "einstein" - a single connected tile that can tile the plane only aperiodically.  They call their tile the "hat".  Write a program to generate a finite patch of a tiling of the plane by hats.
[image]

### Details

The program must output a sequence of tiles that make up the patch.  Each tile must be given in the form of its 13 (or 14 - see below) vertices, listed in order around the tile either clockwise or anticlockwise.  Each vertex must be given in the form of its **triangular** coordinates, as explained below, and **these coordinates must be integers**.

Triangular coordinates are with respect to a pair of axes at 60 degrees to each other.  A point with triangular coordinates `(u,v)` corresponds to a point with ordinary cartesian coordinates `(u+v/2, v*sqrt(3)/2)`.  An example of a single hat tile has vertices with triangular coordinates

```
[(4,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,7),(6,6),(5,4),(6,4),(6,2),(5,1)]
```

Note that it is possible and allowed for the hat to have a different size and still have integer coordinates, although it must not be a different shape.  The hat has a unique longest side (of length 2 at this scale), which may optionally be bisected by an additional vertex to give 14 vertices.

All output tiles must belong to a valid tiling of the full plane by hats (all related to each other by congruences or reflections). The output must include every tile that intersects a certain square, where this square is large enough that there are at least 1000 such tiles.  (At the above scale, a square of side 120 is sufficient). The program may optionally output further tiles of the tiling that lie outside the square. The same tile should not appear more than once in the output.

The algorithm should theoretically be capable of generating arbitrarily large patches (given the ability to work with arbitrary precision integers).  In particular this means that **algorithms that calculate floating point coordinates and then round them to integers are typically NOT acceptable.**

### Examples

The beginning of the output (corresponding to the first 5 hats) might be:

```
[(12,0),(10,-1),(10,0),(9,0),(10,2),(12,3),(12,4),(13,5),(14,4),(13,2),(14,2),(14,0),(13,-1)]
[(10,2),(9,0),(8,0),(7,-1),(6,0),(7,2),(6,2),(6,3),(8,4),(9,3),(10,4),(12,4),(12,3)]
[(2,-2),(4,-1),(4,0),(5,1),(4,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2),(0,0),(1,-1),(0,-2),(0,-4),(1,-4)]
[(6,0),(7,-1),(6,-2),(6,-3),(4,-4),(3,-3),(2,-4),(1,-4),(2,-2),(4,-1),(4,0),(6,2),(7,2)]
[(4,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,7),(6,6),(5,4),(6,4),(6,2),(5,1)]
...
```

The output can be in any reasonable form, such as a linefeed-delimited sequence of lists of pairs as above.

The picture below shows a possible output converted to graphical form. Note that the program itself does not need to produce any graphical output (although obviously it is useful for testing).
[image]

This is code golf, so the shortest program in each language wins.

Related: [Draw the GKMS aperiodic tile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259390/draw-the-gkms-aperiodic-tile)

Comment: 1. There is no input.  The program should simply output the coordinates of tiles as described.  2. There are no partial tiles.  The output should be exactly as described.  It should include every tile that intersects the square, and is allowed to include others, but all tiles output must belong to a tiling of the plane by hats.

Comment: The specifications reads: "All output tiles must belong to a valid tiling of the full plane by hats (all related to each other by congruences or reflections). The output must include every tile that intersects a certain square, where this square is large enough that there are at least 1000 such tiles. (At the above scale, a square of side 120 is sufficient). The program may optionally output further tiles of the tiling that lie outside the square. The same tile should not appear more than once in the output."

Comment: Outputting 5 tiles would not qualify, because 5<1000.  Terminating with a memory overflow would be acceptable (although somewhat perverse) provided the task is completed as described first.  Not sure what the issue is here...?

Answer (score 2):

## Generate a naïve `isEven()`

We've all seen the memes of a beginner programmer writing an `isEven()` function that looks something like this:

```py
def isEven(num):
    if (num == 0):
        return True
    elif (num == 1):
        return False
    # and so on
```

You and I know this is tedious to do by hand, so let's write a program to make this function for us.

## Task

Write a program that accepts a positive integer `n` and outputs a valid naïve `isEven()` function that can check all integers from `0` up to and including `n`.
The resulting function can be in any language, so long as it:

1. Is named `isEven`, and
2. Accepts a single parameter, `num` (integer), and
3. Explicitly checks whether `num` is equal to each integer from `0` to `n`, inclusive (i.e. no `else` for the last case), and
4. Uses `1` `if` statement and `n - 1` `else if` statements (or the equivalent for your resulting language, but not ternary operators) across `n` lines, and
5. Returns a [truthy or falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value **for the language of the resulting function** on a new line after each check. This must be an explicit value, not a calculation (e.g. `True` not `num%2`).

You can assume `n` and `num` are both valid positive integers (i.e. no error checking necessary).

Your resulting function will be at least `2(n+1) + 1` lines, since each value up to `n` requires 2 lines; one for the check, and one for the return.
The `+1` in parenthesis comes from the need to check `0`, and the `+ 1` outside the parenthesis comes from the function declaration.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes win.
Also, [standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), and standard exclusions are forbidden.

**Please put the resulting language in your title (e.g. `Jelly --> C++, n bytes`)**.

## Test cases

Resulting language: Python

```py
# n = 1
def isEven(num):
    if num == 0:
        return True
    elif num == 1:
        return False
```

```py
# n = 10
def isEven(num):
    if num == 0:
        return True
    elif num == 1:
        return False
    elif num == 2:
        return True
    elif num == 3:
        return False
    elif num == 4:
        return True
    elif num == 5:
        return False
    elif num == 6:
        return True
    elif num == 7:
        return False
    elif num == 8:
        return True
    elif num == 9:
        return False
    elif num == 10:
        return True
```

Edit: remove parenthesis from test case

Edit: remove parenthesis from function name

Edit: add condition about explicit true/false return

Edit: fix typo in second condition

Comment: What if the target language doesn't use trailing `()` in functions?

Comment: Instead of `return True` and `return True` would it be permitted to write `return num%2`?

Comment: The trailing `()` don't really matter since the byte count of the resulting function doesn't count toward the score. Python technically doesn't require parenthesis around the conditional.

Edit: I think you meant around the function declaration? So long as the function symbol is `isEven`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: No, it must be a truthy or falsey value, not a truthy or falsey calculation.

Comment: It's not hard to learn the `x%2<1` trick...

Comment: So, the output is in our _choice_ of language, and not necessarily the language our solution is in?

Comment: @Shaggy that's correct

Comment: Would it be allowed to use a certain programming language as the output language, if that language's closest equivalent to an `if/else` statement *is* a ternary operator?  (For example, many functional programming languages - for example in Scheme, `(if (= n 0) #t (if (= n 1) #f ...))`  )

Answer (score 2):

## Finitely generated subgroups of free groups

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [mathematics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) [abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Suppose you are given the free group \$F_n\$ on \$n\$ generators\${}^1\$, a finite subset \$S\$ of \$F_n\$, and an element \$x \in F_n\$.  Then there is an algorithm to determine whether \$x\$ is in the subgroup generated\${}^2\$ by \$S\$, as follows:

- Start with a directed graph with a single "base" vertex, and no edges.
- For each element of \$S\$, add a cycle to the graph according to the corresponding free group word.  Start at the base vertex; for each generator \$g_n\$ in the word, add an arrow labelled by \$n\$; for each inverse of a generator \$g_n^{-1}\$ in the word, add an arrow in the opposite direction labelled by \$n\$; and end at the base vertex.
- If there is a pair of edges with the same label and with either the same source or the same destination, merge those two edges and the two vertices at the other end.  (Except that merging two vertices is not necessary if the two edges have the same source and the same destination.)
- Iterate the previous step until there is no such pair of edges left.
- Now follow the graph from the base vertex, according to the reduced free group word corresponding to \$x\$.  For each generator \$g_n\$ in the word, look for an edge with source at the current vertex and label \$n\$, and move to the destination of that edge.  For each generator \$g_n^{-1}\$ in the word, look for an edge with target at the current vertex and label \$n\$, and move to the source of that edge.

  - If at any point, you do not find such an edge, then \$x \notin \langle S \rangle\$.
  - If at the end, you end up back at the base vertex, then \$x \in \langle S \rangle\$; otherwise, \$x \notin \langle S \rangle\$.

(I plan to give an example of the operation of this algorithm; but I do not have time at the moment to generate the required graph diagrams.)

### Task

Your task is: given a finite subset \$S\$ of a free group \$F_n\$ and an element \$x \in F_n\$, determine whether \$x\$ is in the subgroup generated by \$S\$.  (Note: we are *not* asking to determine whether \$x\$ is in the *normal* subgroup generated by \$S\$; that problem is undecidable in general.)

You are not required to use the above algorithm.  On the other hand, your program or function must always terminate in finite time; so for example, that rules out a naive algorithm just taking all possible products of elements of \$S\$ and their inverses and determining whether you eventually find \$x\$ in the output.

### Input

You will be given a list of free group elements, and a second input giving another free group element.  Possible input formats for free group elements include:

- An element of a built-in free group type.
- A string in the form `abCbcA` where the generators are `a` through `z` and for example `C` represents the inverse of the generator `c`.  You may assume the string is in reduced form, so for example it will not contain either `Cc` or `cC`.

If you like, you could also take a single list of free group elements, and use the first element as \$x\$ and the rest of the list as \$S\$.

If it is useful, you may assume the list of subgroup generators is nonempty, and also that \$x\$ and each element of the list is not the empty word.

### Output

A truthy/falsey value according to whether or not \$x \in \langle S \rangle\$, where \$S\$ is the set of elements of the list for the first input and \$x\$ is the second input.

### Examples

```
[aa, ab], a -> False
[aa, ab], ba -> False
[aa, ab], Ba -> True
[aBc, bc], aBBCbA -> True
[aBc, bc], abc -> False
[aaaaa, aaa], a -> True
```

### Score

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): the shortest code in bytes for any given programming language wins.

---

\${}^1\$ The free group \$F_n\$ on \$n\$ generators can be described as the reduced words in the alphabet consisting of formal symbols \$g_1, g_1^{-1}, g_2, g_2^{-1}, \ldots, g_n, g_n^{-1}\$.  Here, "reduced" means that \$g_i\$ and \$g_i^{-1}\$ never appear next to each other in the word.  To multiply two words, concatenate them and then iteratively cancel out pairs \$g_i g_i^{-1}\$ or \$g_i^{-1} g_i\$ in the middle.  This has the empty word as an identity element, and to find the inverse of a reduced word, reverse the order and transform each \$g_i\$ into \$g_i^{-1}\$ and vice versa.

\${}^2\$ The subgroup of \$F_n\$ generated by a subset \$S \subseteq F_n\$ is the smallest subset of \$F_n\$ which contains \$S\$, also contains the identity element, and is closed under multiplication and inverses.  This can alternately be described as the set of elements of \$F_n\$ which can be formed as the product of some finite sequence of elements of \$S\$, and/or their inverses.

Comment: This could benefit from definitions of the relevant mathematical terms, such as "free group".

Comment: @Bbrk24 OK, I added some brief definitions in footnotes.

Answer (score 2):

### A Phinary Library

I've been away from SE/SO for quite some time now and have decided to revisit a SE that I used to go on way before I made this account, so I wanted to draft a challenge that I have had rolling around in my head for a bit, fitting the tags [numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers) [data-structures](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

## Challenge

Knowing what base phi/'phinary' numbers are, as explained in the background to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/standardise-a-phinary-number) and in [this one too](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204185/base-phi-converter-time), your task is to implement a set of arithmetic routines/functions that handle this numeric system, at least for addition and subtraction of two phinary numbers from each other.

You will need to write code that performs the following three operations:

1. A chunk that adds two phinary numbers
2. A chunk that subtracts two phinary numbers
3. A chunk that outputs a phinary number in standard form

I'm refraining from calling them functions or whatnot, as you are totally free to organise your code in any way you see fit.

You may take *normalised phinary* input via whatever way you choose (hardcoded into ROM, through `stdin`, whatever) and in whatever format (for example, you can encode whether it's addition or subtraction in the input itself) and print (or output in some other way) the *normalised* phinary result.

Do not use built-in base conversion facilities, the arithmetic has to be done directly in phinary. The intermediate phinary can be "unstandardised": only the input and output must be in normal form.

See the following test cases for some examples:

```
INPUT             OUTPUT
----------------------------
10000.0001
         +
    100.01    =   10100.0101 
----------------------------
 1010.0001
         -
      10.0    =    1000.0001
----------------------------
      10.1
         +
  1000.001    =     1010.101
```

Your code should handle and be correct for arbitrary sized phinary input. If your language has a specific size limit (such as old Befunge, or you're writing 6502 assembly code), you should handle inputs that are at least 33% of the space constraint in size (so, 21626 digits for 6502 assembly, for example).

The shortest code in bytes wins. If your code is textual source, bytes are counted according to UTF-8 encoding sizes.

---

### Things I'm still not sure about

What other limits should I impose?
How should I better formulate the challenge?

Comment: While the challenges you linked explain phinary quite well, I think it would be worth having at least a brief explanation in the body of your challenge as well, even if it's just copied, pasted, and cited from them. I'd also like to see some testcases where weird phinary rules apply, as right now your test cases make it look like phinary is just binary.

Comment: "The shortest code in bytes wins. If your code is textual source, bytes are counted according to UTF-8 encoding sizes." See [How to count bytes FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10145)

Answer (score 2):

## [Detect Maxima Using Persistent Homology](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262268/detect-maxima-using-persistent-homology)

Answer (score 2):

## [XOR of independent Bernoulli variables](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262140/xor-of-independent-bernoulli-variables)

Comment: Nice challenge, my only suggestion is to point out that the XOR is 1 when the number of 1's is odd.

Answer (score 2):

## [Reverse Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262763/reverse-conways-game-of-life)

Comment: What should the behavior be for gardens of eden?

Comment: gardens of eden will not be part of the input, you can output nonsense, fail or not terminate for them, I will add it to the challenge. that's what I was trying to convey with the multiple solutions constraint

Comment: determining if a configuration is a garden of eden could be an interesting challenge

Answer (score 2):

## [Translate the keitai input method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262329/translate-the-keitai-input-method)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Are solutions required to cycle back to a-column, or are inputs guaranteed to never contain extraneous keypresses?

Comment: @UnrelatedString it must cycle back; I've added a test case for this

Answer (score 2):

## Sum of Two Intervals

A k-th interval plus an m-th interval is a (k+m-1)th interval. An interval with p semitones plus one with q semitones is one with (p+q) semitones. Given two intervals, get their sum. Relations between interval and semitones is listed below.

| Interval | Double Diminished | Diminished | Minor | Perfect | Major | Augmented | Double Augmented |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| unison (1st) | -2* | -1* | - | 0 | - | 1 | 2 |
| 2nd | -1* | 0 | 1 | - | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3rd | 1 | 2 | 3 | - | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 4th | 3 | 4 | - | 5 | - | 6 | 7 |
| 5th | 5 | 6 | - | 7 | - | 8 | 9 |
| 6th | 6 | 7 | 8 | - | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 7th | 8 | 9 | 10 | - | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| octave (8th) | 10 | 11 | - | 12 | - | 13 | 14 |

<sup>* Negative distance doesn't exist but it can be added 12 until non-negative</sup>

For larger interval, k-th interval has 12 more semitones than the same type of (k-7)-th interval. Triple Augmented is 1 more semitone than Double Augmented, Triple Diminished is 1 less semitone than Double Diminished, etc.

## IO format

- The interval would likely get inputted as one argument
- You can take Double Diminished/Diminished/Minor/Perfect/Major/Augmented/Double Augmented as -2/-1/a/b/c/1/2, where `a`, `b`, `c` are different, zero or non-integer
- You can take Double Diminished/Diminished/Minor/Perfect/Major/Augmented/Double Augmented as -3/-2/-1/0/1/2/3
- Same applies to output
- You needn't handle invalid input like "Diminished 1st", "Major 4th" or "Perfect 2nd".

## Test cases

```
Minor 2nd + Major 3rd = Perfect 4th
Major 2nd + Major 2nd = Major 3rd
Major 3rd + Major 3rd = Augmented 5th
Augmented 2nd + Augmented 3rd = Triple Augmented 4th
Double Diminished 6th + Double Diminished 7th = 5 Times Diminished 12th
Augmented 1st + Minor 2nd = Major 2nd
```

or testing friendly,

```
[m,2]+[M,3]=[0,4]
[M,2]+[M,2]=[M,3]
[M,3]+[M,3]=[1,5]
[1,2]+[1,3]=[3,4]
[-2,6]+[-2,7]=[-5,12]
[1,1]+[m,2]=[M,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

## The next popcount

Given a substring of [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), number of 1's in binary expansion of n, find the next term.

If there's no answer, output something unambiguous to a term. If there's multiple possible answers, output any subset of the answers(Empty set allowed which may act as if no answer)

## Test Cases

```
2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3 -> 4  (X001, X010, X011, X100, X101, X110 where X matches /10*/)
2, 4 -> DNE
5, 1 -> 2 (11111, 100000)
```

Comment: This feels like a combination of determining whether a substring is valid and finding a possible next term, although maybe they're close enough to be the same challenge

Answer (score 2):

## Chamber of Reflection

### Background

A ray of light is fired from the top left vertex of an `MxN` Chamber, where `M` a denotes the width and `N` denotes the height of the chamber. The ray of light advances one grid space per second. Given that `T` is the number of seconds to be simulated, calculate the number of reflections in this time frame.

For example, given `5 4 11` (ie. `M = 5, N = 4, T = 11`):

```
\/\  [
/\ \ [
\ \ \[
   \/[
-----
There would be 4 reflections, so the output should be 4.
```

Note that a reflection only counts if the ray of light has already bounced off it, so for example, given `5 4 10`:

```
\/\  [
/\ \ [
  \ \[
   \/[
-----
There would only be 3 reflections, so the output should be 3.
```

### Your Task

- Sample Input: M, the width of the chamber, N, the height of the chamber, and T, the time frame. These are all numbers.
- Output: Return the number of reflections.

**Explained Examples**

```
Input => Output
1 1 10 => 9 

Chamber:
\[
-

The ray will be reflected back and forth a total of 9 times.
```

```
Input => Output
5 1 10 => 9 

Chamber:
\/\/\[

The ray will be reflected back and forth a total of 9 times. It will first go left to right, then go backwards right to left.
```

```
Input => Output
4 5 16 => 6 

Chamber:
\/\ [
/\ \[
\ \/[
 \/\[
\/\/[
----

The ray will be reflected back and forth a total of 6 times.
```

```
Input => Output
100 100 1 => 0 

Chamber:
\ ... [
...    x100
-x100


The ray never touches a wall, and is never reflected, so output 0.
```

**Test Cases**

```
Input => Output
5 4 11 => 4
5 4 10 => 3
1 1 10 => 9
5 1 10 => 9
4 5 16 => 6
100 100 1 => 0

3 2 9 => 5
3 2 10 => 6
6 3 18 => 5
5 3 16 => 7
1 1 100 => 99
4 4 100 => 24
2398 2308 4 => 0
10000 500 501 => 1
500 10000 502 => 1
```

Bonus points (not really): Listen to DeMarco's song [Chamber of Reflection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQsF3pzOc54) while solving this.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Answer (score 2):

## [Compute this fractal matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263364/compute-this-fractal-matrix)

Comment: once again - why so specific? why can't I just return *any* two distinct values, and not just a truthy and a falsy value?

Comment: @RubenVerg As far as I can tell most challenges about computing matrices only allow to output the numbers that actually appear in the matrix. I removed the restrictions about the print formatting, but as the numbers in the matrix are 0 and 1, allowing any two distinct values feels overly general. Do you have any specific (type of) value pair in mind.

Answer (score 2):

First attempt at a question. Feedback appreciated.

---

## Calculating Complete Graphs

[image]

The above picture shows a complete graph with `7` vertices. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), "a complete graph is a simple undirected graph in which every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a unique edge."

Today, we're going to be *repairing* incomplete graphs.

Given a 2D Array (representing an incomplete graph) where each inner array represents a vertex, **determine the number of additional edges required to create a complete graph.**

---

Here's an example:

```
[[2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [3]]
```

And this would generate a graph that looks like this:

[image: Incomplete]

To make this graph complete, it is obvious that we only need to add **two** edges.

[image: Complete]

For completeness (<s>haha</s>), here's what the completed 2D array would look like (but this is not what your program should output):

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

*Notes:*

1. There is an array for every vertex, but your code should be able to account for empty arrays (which means the vertex is originally not connected to any other vertex).
2. I don't know if this is important, but you can assume the vertexes listed in each inner array will be listed in increasing order. Also, no vertex will be connected to itself.
3. If vertex a is connected to vertex b, then vertex b is connected to vertex a. Symmetric.

---

And yeah, that's pretty much it. Here are some test cases:

```
Input                                                           Output

[[], [], []]                                                    3
[[2], [1], [4], [3]]                                            4 
[[2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [3]]                                2
[[2, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3], [1]]                              6
[[3, 4, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2], [3, 6], [1, 5]]          8
```

---

This question is tagged **code-golf**. Standard rules apply.

Comment: Hi! Welcome!!! Question looks good, sounds a bit trivial tho, can be solved using math formula `(n(n-1) - x)/2` where n is the number vertices and x the number of elements in the flatten input

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I must admit the solution is easier than I originally thought. I'll attempt to remake it in a way that invites more creativity.

Answer (score 2):

## [Solve quadratic equations when 1+1=0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263452/solve-quadratic-equations-when-11-0)

*This is the code-golf version of this challenge, I also created a [fastest-code version](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25896#25896) that focuses on solving one (important) special case*

Answer (score 2):

## My math license got revoked

Your task is to replicate the method described in https://xkcd.com/410/.

Not going to develop the question more until I have enough time to get some test cases together and make sure that there are complex friendly numbers.

I'm sandboxing this for the future, but here's a (work-in-progress) python reference implementation:

```
def is_divisible(a, b):
return a // b == a / b

def sum_divisors(a):
    divisors = []

    for real_part in range(1, a.real):
        for complex_part in range(1, a.imag):

            number_to_test_if_divisor = complex(real_part, complex_part)
            if is_divisible(a, number_to_test_if_divisor):
                divisors.append(number_to_test_if_divisor)

    return sum(divisors)

def is_friendly(a, b):
    return sum_divisors(a) / a == sum_divisors(b) / b


a = complex(input("a: "))
b = complex(input("b: "))

print(is_friendly(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Compute the logarithm of a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263530/compute-the-logarithm-of-a-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

## Base-10 to bijective base-10

Convert base-10 positive integer (base-10 number using digits `0123456789`) to bijective base-10 (base-10 number using digits `123456789A`, where `A` means 10).

Shortest code wins.

You can also choose another symbol in place of the `A`.

Comment: It may be a duplicate of [this challange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54105/all-your-bijective-base-are-belong-to-us)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cutting a Circular Pizza Vertically](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264044/cutting-a-circular-pizza-vertically)

Answer (score 2):

## [First odd then even indices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264409/first-odd-then-even-indices)

Answer (score 2):

## [Walk by walls in a room](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264421/walk-by-walls-in-a-room)

Comment: It is unclear where one test case ends and the next begins

Comment: @mousetail Just clarified it

Answer (score 2):

## [Zeckendorf to F(4k+2) representation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264604/78410)

Answer (score 2):

### [Minimal number of jumps to reach a square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264738/78039)

Answer (score 2):

## [Draw numbers as dice patterns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265159/convert-numbers-to-dice-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

## [Normalize a Gaussian GCD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264733/normalize-a-gaussian-gcd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264793/inverse-trigonometric-functions)

---

### Example equations using complex logarithm:

\$ \sin^{-1}(z)=-i \cdot \ln(\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz) \$

\$ \cos^{-1}(z)=-i \cdot \ln(\sqrt{z^2-1}+z) \$

\$ \tan^{-1}(z)=\frac{i}{2} \cdot \ln(\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}) \$

Answer (score 2):

## [Prefix code generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264747/78410)

Answer (score 2):

### Pseudo-Quantum Bogosort

Quantum Bogosort is as follows:

1. Quantumly randomise the list, such that there is no way of knowing what order the list is in until it is observed. This will divide the universe into O(n!) universes; however, the division has no cost, as it happens constantly anyway.
2. If the list is not sorted, destroy the universe. (This operation is left as an exercise to the reader.)
3. All remaining universes contain lists which are sorted.

[Source](http://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort)

Given that we cannot destroy the universe, the next best thing is to destroy a thread!

The challenge is as follows:
Make a new thread for each possible permutation of a list and if the list is not sorted, destroy the thread.

### Rules

Input is a list of length 4 or less

Output is a sorted list and I guess the number of the thread that is sorted? This part is iffy...

This is standard code-golf

Answer (score 2):

## Volume of a squaricililinder

*Inspired by an interestingly-shaped glass at a cafe.*

### WHAT THE HECK IS A SQUARICILILINDER!?!?!

A squaricililinder is a prism with a square at one end and a circle at the other. The circle is as small as possible while being able to fit the square at the other end inside.

The width of the glass increases at a constant rate as you go up it.

### Now what's the challenge?

Given the height of a squaricililinder and the diameter of the circle on it, calculate the area of the squaricililinder.

### How am I supposed to calculate it?

It's simple, all you need to do is plug in the height \$h\$ and the diameter \$d\$ to this simple formula:
$$\small\underbrace{4\times\left( \int_0^h \int_0^{\frac d{\sqrt 2} }\frac yh\times\sqrt{ 1-\frac{x^2\times\left(6-4\sqrt2\right)}d } dx dy\right) + \left(\frac{d^2}2 \times h \right)}_\textrm{I hope I got the formula right...}$$
It was obtained by calculating the area of the cuboid inside and then doing some two-dimensional integrals on the circular parts.

### Can you give me an example implementation?

Sure, here's an ungolfed and slow example in Python + `sympy`:

```python
from sympy import *

x, y, d, h = symbols("x, y, d, h")

def calculate_area_of_shape(diameter: float, height: float) -> float:
    
    formula_in_integral = (y / h) * sqrt(1 - (((x ** 2) * (6 - 4 * sqrt(2))) / d))
    
    integral_part = integrate(integrate(formula_in_integral, (x, 0, d / sqrt(2))), (y, 0, h))
    
    actual_formula = 4 * integral_part + ((d ** 2) / 2) * h
    
    return actual_formula.subs(d, diameter).subs(h, height)
```

### Anything else?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: Can you be more specific how a squaricililinder is constructed? I assume it's made by connecting points on the circle to those on the square. But how do we match the points? By fraction of the perimeter? By angle of the center?

Comment: You should add test-cases to make it easier to verify different approaches (your examples times out on ato)

Comment: You should make it more clear if you are talking about the volume or the (surface) area

Comment: For `h=d=1` your equation [gives a volume of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4*%28integral+from+0+to+1+of+%28integral+from+0+to+%281%2Fsqrt%282%29%29+of+%28y*sqrt%281-%28x%5E2*%286-4sqrt%282%29%29%29%29%29dx%29+dy%29%2B+1%2F2)  `1.8727`, which is more than the volume of a cylinder with height `h` and diameter `d`  (`pi*(d/2)²*h= 0.785`). But the way I understood your description the shape should be contained in that cylinder

Comment: I don't understand what the width of the glass is, which you say goes up at a constant rate. And I still have my question about how the squaricylinder is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

## Median of Chi-Square

Output the IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point number represented by the following binary decomposition:

```
Sign, Exponent, Mantissa
0, 01111101, 11010001110110101101101
```

This is the most accurate approximation of the median of the chi-squared distribution \$\chi^2(1)\$, which is approximately \$0.454936423119572751942516646979649\$ in decimal. There is no known closed form of this value.

Comment: Worth noting this value is `1055452525` in decimal and `3EE8ED6D` in Hex.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBJuXMvOSc0pRUBZvikpTMfL0Mu6WlJWm6FjcN03LyE0sU0jQ0qzPzShQSbU0MLQwMDLWMTI1MrYtSS0qL8rQ0NMCKtDTVEjWta6EaXUDKcxMz8zTK8jNTNKu5FBQgRiXZAg2zBnILioBK0jSUVNN0FFQrlHSAwjpAs4CCQJOSNIFqoGYtWAChAQ) fall under "Hard-coding the output"?

Comment: @bsoelch No. That's clever, actually.

Comment: This is \$\frac{15265133}{2^{25}}\$, right?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yeah.

Comment: Do you have to output exactly this number? Or can you output anything which rounds off to this, when treated as a single floating-point number? The exact number in decimal is `0.4549364149570465087890625`

Comment: @CommandMaster The task is to output the floating-point number approximation, not the number itself.

Comment: @DannyuNDos The exact floating-point number in decimal is `0.4549364149570465087890625`.

Comment: @CommandMaster Since the task is to output the floating-point number, that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I think I am confused. Is the following statement correct? "A solution is valid iff it takes no input, and outputs (according to the standard I/O rules) a number, that if rounded to a single-precision floating-point number will round to \$\frac{15265133}{2^25}\$". In particular, would a Mathematica answer which symbolically outputs the exact number be valid?

Comment: @CommandMaster Dunno whether Mathematica has floating-point numbers, so I cannot really answer that.

Comment: Is `lambda:0.4549364149` a valid Python answer? It outputs a double-precision float which isn't equal to the approximation, but if rounded to single-precision it's equal

Answer (score 2):

## [Sums of sum of divisors in sublinear time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265114/sums-of-sum-of-divisors-in-sublinear-time)

Answer (score 2):

## How sorted is this array

Given an array output the minimum number of swaps needed to sort that array

### Examples

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   ->  0
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]   ->  1
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]   ->  2
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]   ->  3
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]   ->  4

[3, 5, 1, 11, 7, 3] -> 3
```

### Rules

- You can assume that the elements of the array are positive integers
- There might be duplicate elements
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins

### Optional additional requirement

Solve the problem in \$O(n²)\$

---

### Meta

- Would you consider [this challange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197536/swaps-to-sort-an-array) to be a duplicate? My solution only asks for the number of swaps, which seems to be a much easier task than finding the actual pairs of indices
  These twp challenges I found are very similar but not exactly the same:
  [sorting networks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261248/how-many-sorting-networks),
  [swaps in bubble sort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5011/swaps-needed-to-sort-an-array-in-bubble-sort-method)

Comment: Is the input a permutation? If it is the answer is the length of the input minus the number of cycles in the permutation, which seems like it would be a simple modification to an existing question

Answer (score 2):

## Unique String Deletions

You are given a string `s`, where `s.length <= 42`, and an integer `k`, where `k <= s.length`.
All regular test cases have totals < 2147483648, but bonuses exceed this value. If limited by int32, return modulo of value.

Return the count of all unique strings obtained by deleting k characters. Fastest algorithm wins. In case of a tie by algorithmic complexity, whoever has the most bonus cases wins.

Test cases: These are the sums of all `f(s, k)` from k=0 to k=s.length

```
"" = 1
"a" = 2
"aaaaa" = 6
"meow" = 16
"acacc" = 17
"cbcab" = 26
"abcacc" = 37
"cbabca" = 50
"alifra" = 63
"caadbac" = 87
"abbbacbb" = 78
"abbbbbabab" = 97
"doggaggy" = 112
"abbabacca" = 162
"abbbacbbaa" = 218
"isosceles" = 384
"armageddon" = 720
"123456789abcdef" = 32768
"supercalifragilistic" = 812760
```

### Bonus cases: (Used as tiebreaker)

```
"arithmosesquippedaliophobia" = 80375252
"antidisestablishmentarianism" = 174600720
"pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism" = 644909314
"supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" = 11073277084
"hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia" = 14891636776
```

Comment: There's [a similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/145371/20260) for binary strings with [tag:restricted-time]. Do you think there's room for improving the algorithmic complexity from what the answers there do?

Comment: Shouldn't the empty string output 1?

Comment: I've characterized my solution, and it runs in `3.55e-8*n^(2.19)`

Comment: Using the same approach as the answers in the question @xnor linked you can create a linear-time algorithm

Comment: I'd expect someone will find a linear time solution, and then a lot of answers will copy it, and you will just get a bunch of ties. Perhaps you can have the number of allowed deletions be different than `s.length`?

Comment: From what i found on SO: [It's a classic DP] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151483/how-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-subsequences-of-a-string

Comment: @CommandMaster changed the question to use number of deletions as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

## Build the smallest self driving Car

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your goal is building the smallest self driving car to get from `A` to `B`.

The car is a point mass of 1kg and has a steering wheel to turn left and right, as well as an accelerator pedal to accelerate and brake. Furthermore it is equipped with LIDAR: If 0° is the forward direction, it has a laser every 10° from -90° to +90°. Each of these lasers measures the distance to the next wall. The point `A` is where the car starts witz zero velocity, pointing north. The destination `B` is an area where the car has to stop to finish the trip (it can be facing any direction).

Your job is to write a function that is called every second, to steer your car to the `B` area, *without* crashing into the wall.

```python
def car(lidar, speed):
    # lidar is an array of 19 floating point numbers
    # speed is an integer
    steering = ... # can be any integer from -3 to 3 and refers to a multiple of 10° (eg -2 means -20°) the car is turned in this step.
    acceleration = ... # can be any of [-1, 0, 1] and refers to the acceleration in `m/s` for the next step
    # first the car is turned by the indicated amount, then the acceleration is added to the current velocity, and then we take a velocity-sized step in the current direction

    return steering, acceleration
```

The function must be deterministic and a black box function, that is, it can only communicate to the outside world via the inputs arguments and the returned values. The function must be as small as possible (measured in bytes).

If the car crashes into a wall, it will be disqualified.

[image: the car with lidar]

## Map

the map will need to be determined it will be a closed non-self intersecting polygon. Here is an example but it will be a longer and maybe a little bit more complicated:

[image]

---

## Discussion

- EDIT: I just remembered there was [Lab Rat Race: an exercise in genetic algorithms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44707/lab-rat-race-an-exercise-in-genetic-algorithms) where we did something similar. So maybe it would make sense to take the challenge in a slightly different direction.
- EDIT2: There is an almost identical challenge in http://janismac.github.io/ControlChallenges/ (go to the menu with the little squares and choose "Vehicle Steering" or "Vehicle Racing"). After playing around with this I think a combination of golfing code and time would be nice.

---

I'd obviously have to write a controller and come up with a good map that is doable with the velocity/direction constraints. Ideally with some graphical output for the participants to debug their car.

1. Shall there be multiple maps?
2. Are the discrete actions a good idea? (And are the ranges any good?) I think for the velocity it is nice so the car can come to a full stop in the target area.
3. Should the steering be limited when the velocity is higher?
4. Currently it feels like this will end up as just as a compression challenge i.e. who can hardcode a good sequence of steering inputs. I'm not sure this is all that fun. Are there other challenge modes or variations for this setting that would be more interesting? (The other thing I had in mind was giving the players a fixed code-budget and measuring how far they can get in the map.)
5. Should the cars be allowed to have some memory between each step? (e.g. limited to a certain number of bits) - after the update from above I think it would make sense to allow some (or maybe even an unlimited) amount of memory between each step. But still it would be nice to have some sort of restriction.

Comment: I agree with point 4, I think this is already hard enough and golfing wouldn't make it more interesting. Perhaps a [tag:test-battery] [tag:code-challenge], with the score based on how far the car gets on average? Maybe with hidden tests to prevent overfitting

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes that would definitely fit. I think I'd like people to overfit in the sense that they do a fixed route. But if we'd make a score based on distance we'd have to impose some other limit or challenge, I think?

Answer (score 2):

## Add two rational numbers... esoterically

### Objective

Build a binary operator \$\star : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\$ such that, there exists a bijection \$i : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}\$ such that, for every integer \$M\$ and \$N\$, \$M \star N = i^{-1}(i(M) + i(N))\$ holds.

Or in mathematical terms, build a binary operator \$\star\$ that admits a group isomorphism from \$(\mathbb{Z}, \star)\$ to \$(\mathbb{Q}, +)\$.

### I/O Format

Flexible. Standard loopholes apply.

### Scoring

This is a [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) challenge. The submission whose the **asymptotic** worst-case time complexity of \$\star\$ is the fastest wins.

The parameter \$n\$ for the time complexity is \$s(M) + s(N)\$, where \$s\$ is defined as follows:

- \$s(0) = s(-1) = 0\$.
- For every integer \$D > 0\$, \$s(D) = \lfloor \log_2 D \rfloor + 1\$.
- For every integer \$D < -1\$, \$s(D) = \lfloor \log_2 (-D-1) \rfloor + 1\$.

The shortness of your code is a tiebreaker. That is, this challenge is secondarily [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Notes and Rules

Note that each bijection \$i\$ induces \$\star\$ uniquely. As such, your submission must specify your choice of \$i\$.

Comment: How would you score built-ins (e.g. for arithmetic operations on integers, int to string, ...)?   O(1), the complexity of the languages implementation or the complexity of the best known algorithm?

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest having something else other than code-length as the tie breaker, according to [Using shortest code as a tie-breaking winning criterion in code-challenge questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8195/92727)

Comment: I thought of an interesting solution, so I removed my comments regarding interesting solutions

Comment: Is O(1) possible on word-RAM model?

Comment: @l4m2 it depends on what operators you allow, but O(n) is definitely possible

Answer (score 2):

## [Transpose a multidimensional array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265768/transpose-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: These kinds of operations are common in libraries/languages for scientific computing, like MATLAB/Octave or in python numpy/pytorch. In these languages you usually find a function like https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html or https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html that make it easier to comprehend what dimensions are moved to which other dimensions. Could you maybe phrase your challenge also in terms of these functions? I think it is easier to understand if you explain how the dimensions need to be moved (instead of showing this example).

Comment: This is also a [builtin](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/transpose.html#transposing-tensors) in BQN.

Answer (score 2):

## [Visualise the Euclidean GCD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265949/visualise-the-euclidean-gcd)

Comment: Again, going to assume [tag:code-golf]?

Answer (score 2):

## Is this your answer? [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

NOTE: The scoring criterion for this is currently broken. I'll fix it at some point ™

---

In this challenge, you must write an answer that distinguishes itself from all previous answers. No matter what input is passed in, it must output one of two consistent values. Your answer must output one value, marked as "truthy", when your answer's code is input, and the other value, marked as "falsy", when the code of at least one previous answer is input. Whichever value it outputs when anything else is input does not matter as long as it outputs one of the two values.

However, you are not only trying to distinguish your answer from others, but also to trick previous answers into thinking your source code is their own and outputting their truthy value.

Your answer's score is \$\frac{\text{byte count} + 2}{\text{tricked answers } \cdot \text{ answers that don't trick you}}\$, where "tricked answers" is the number of previous answers that output their truthy value when given your code, and "answers that don't trick you" is the number of previous answers for which your answer correctly returns the falsy value. Your answer must trick at least one previous answer and not be tricked by at least one previous answer.

For example, if the first answer was the Python program `print(1)`, then a valid second answer would be the JavaScript function `x=>x.includes('x')`, which checks if the input string contains a `x`, returning true for itself, false for the singlee previous answer, and either true or false for any input string. As the previous answer prints a 1 when given this code, this would score \$\frac{18+2}{1 \cdot 1} = 20\$.

---

First answer (will be posted along with the question):

## 1: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 8 bytes

```python
print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1Dz/38A)

Outputs 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy.

Comment: So I insta-win by having a 0 byte answer that tricks at least 1 program?

Comment: @lyxal Yes, but it'd need to be a zero-byte answer that outputs one of two consistent values no matter what input is provided, so no Vyxal zero-byte cat for you. I don't think a zero-byte answer is possible, and tricking at least one program (the first) is guaranteed.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJPIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiVGhpcydsbCBhbHdheXMgb3V0cHV0IHRoZSBlbXB0eSBzdHJpbmcsIHdoaWNoIGlzIGZhbHNleSJd)

Comment: @lyxal Yes, but it also needs to output a different, truthy value when your program is input.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJIIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiQWx3YXlzIHByaW50cyAxMDAsIHdoaWNoIGlzIHRydXRoeSJd)

Comment: @lyxal It needs to output a falsy value when `print(1)` is input, a truthy value when your source code is input, and one of those two values for any other possible input.

Comment: The first answer doesn't comply with that rule, so it should be considered invalid.

Comment: @lyxal The first answer doesn't have to output a falsy value because there are no answers before it which would require outputting said falsy value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148916/discussion-between-lyxal-and-emanresu-a).

Comment: Are duplicate answers (identical source-code as previous answer) allowed?

Comment: @bsoelch ... yes, and that results in one more tricked answer for a slightly lower score... this scoring criterion is annoying.

Comment: Just chipping in to say that i dont think identical answers should be allowed, and that if someone really wants to they should be allowed to tank their score in bytes by just trying really hard not to get tricked :-) it just seems right to me in my opinion so thats all i have to say

Comment: The problem is, people could add an answer that is extremely similar to the previous answer, say with a comment added or two, and under the current scoring system do better

Comment: A late true detector has ->0 score

Answer (score 2):

## [Golf a LaTeΧ math expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265852/golf-a-late%ce%a7-math-expression) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Comment: So, just, remove whitespace before non-alphanumeric? am I missing something here?

Comment: @noodleman It's more complicated, sometimes you can remove `{}`, and sometimes you can remove a space before an alphanumeric (in `a b` you can, but not in `\a b`)

Comment: Definitely add test cases reflecting those behaviours

Answer (score 2):

## [Expected number of rounds for this labeling scheme](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266185/expected-number-of-rounds-for-this-labeling-scheme)

Comment: If one simulates ALL runs long enough (say up to length \$10^n\$) then it's deterministic and provably returns the correct answer with enough accuracy. Is that something you want?

Comment: @CommandMaster This is something that I would like to prevent if possible, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. The thing is that all these values are exact rational numbers, meaning that if I wanted to, I could require the answer to be `(numerator, denominator)` pairs and this would prevent simulation answers. But this would be inconvenient for everyone as most languages don't have a built-in fraction type and would have to do extra work to keep track of the numerator and the denominator in the code.

Comment: But then by allowing floating point output, I'm allowing for answers like the one you mentioned by just simulating all possibilities up to a certain point, and that isn't what I want.

Comment: Perhaps you can require that the algorithm is correct theoretically - if floating-point numbers had infinite accuracy.

Comment: @CommandMaster Is that something that is "observable"? I'm worried about setting any unobservable requirements.

Comment: While unobservable requirements are generally discouraged, theoretical correctness is usually an exception. See [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18196/how-can-we-clearly-define-must-work-for-theoretically-large-values) meta post, for example

Comment: @CommandMaster I made an edit with what you suggested. Can you check if the wording is correct, or anything wrong with how I said it?

Answer (score 2):

## With/Without line separator

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

### Challenge

Write a function/program which takes two positive integer \$a\$ and \$b\$ and returns:

1. \$a \times b\$, when the program is in its default form
2. \$a^b\$, when some line separators or instruction separators are removed from the same program

In your answer, please specify what line/instruction separators need to be omitted.

### Test cases:

| a | b | \$a \times b\$ | \$a^b\$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 9 |

### Notes

Avoid using comments if possible
You do not need to handle larger numbers
You may keep some line separators
You cannot reorder instructions

### Example

Assuming the program below calculates \$a \times b\$

```
(a,b) => {
    instruction1;
    instruction2;
    instruction3;
    instruction4;
    instruction5;
    return result;
}
```

The below would calculate \$a^b\$

```
(a,b) => {
    instruction1instruction2;
    instruction3instruction4instruction5;
    return result;
}
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes in each language wins.

Comment: Golfing the difference to `return a*b;-a*b+a**b`?

Comment: @l4m2 yeah this will be trivial for languages like JS where math operations without assignments can be left without causing errors. Do you reckon I should find a way to make it harder?

I'll also remove "Using comments is fine" as it makes it too trivial

Answer (score 2):

## [Find the fairest partition of a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266479/find-the-fairest-partition-of-a-list)

Comment: You should clarify that parts don't have to be continuous, currently it has to be deduced from the examples

Comment: Nice challenge. Shouldn’t the result for the fourth one be zero?

Comment: I’d probably also say absolute difference to be clear.

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted? If so, may a submission take input sorted in descending order rather than ascending?

Answer (score 2):

## How many twisted corners?

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266733/how-many-twisted-corners)

Comment: suggested testcase: `B U2 D2 F` => `0`, Also, is repeating a move legal? (like `U U'` or `F2 F`)

Comment: Is this a [tag:parsing] challenge or is the input format loose? (e.g. RRR instead of R', RR instead of R2)

Comment: @noodleman good point, I'll redefine the input.

Comment: You might want to include a worked example with a GIF or something like that.

Comment: @noodleman right, thanks!

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to have at least one move, or may it be empty?

Answer (score 2):

## [Make Code Printing X Without X](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266614/make-code-printing-x-without-x)

Comment: very similar to [this recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266359/restricted-meta-cat)

Comment: @bsoelch Technically, that challenge is similar to [the original version of this challenge :)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/26075#26075)

Comment: (It turns out that [Neil had the same idea even earlier :)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64591414#64591414))

Answer (score 2):

## Smallest infinite irreducible program

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)

---

A typical constraint for [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) challenges, where the goal is to make your code as long as possible, is that your program must be "irreducible". I.e., no subset of characters can be removed from your program with it still being valid. If your code was `xyz`, none of `x`, `y`, `z`, `xy`, `yz`, or `xz` could do the same task as `xyz`. This makes it impossible to use comments, string literals, long variable names, or whitespace to pad out your code length, but through some trickery it's possible to design a program which can be made arbitrarily large while still being irreducible.

In this challenge, you'll try to golf the setup for this. Your submission will be a finitely sized "base" program, which is irreducible, and which can be increased to an arbitrarily high size through the addition of substrings at a chosen point (or set of points) in the program.

For example, a base program might look like `wx()yz`, and continue to function and be irreducible with the insertion of arbitrarily many `ab`s in between the `()`s (such as `wx(ababab)yz`). You can also require substrings to be inserted in multiple places at once (e.g., you might need a `1` to be appended to the program for each `ab`, so the previous example would look like `wx(ababab)yz111`).

**Scoring:**

Your score is the size in bytes of your base program. Your base program must be irreducible on its own; if the insertion of some minimum number of your chosen substring(s) is necessary for this, those must be included in the score.

**Task:**

Your irreducible program must do any one of the following tasks, of your choice:

- Truth machine: Take an input. If the input is `0`, print `0` and stop. If the input is `1`, print `1` indefinitely
- Arithmetic: Take two inputs, `x` and `y`. Print `x + y²`.
- Constant output: Print the string `Good morning!`

You may write a program or a function. If you choose to write a function, instead of printing you may return the output. For the truth machine task, you must use an infinite list/iterator if you return a value; you must have some way of getting an arbitrary number of `1`s out of the return value in finite time (so you can't just append `1`s to a list infinitely, and return the list once the infinite loop would stop).

Comment: If your code is `xyzw` and `xz` does the job it isn't irreducible, right?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there isn't an infinite set of strings such that none of them are a subsequence of one another, and this challenge is impossible

Comment: How can the program continue to be irreducible after inserting characters? The base program can be obtained by removing a subset of characters from the extended program and is also a valid program.

Comment: See Higman's lemma, which says there isn't such an infinite set

Comment: Oh true, I guess I need to change how the insertion works

Answer (score 2):

## Sub-quadratic base conversion

Write a program that converts a positive integer given in base 10 to its base 2 representation.

Your algorithm must run in a complexity lower that \$O(n^2)\$

### Rules

- You can assume that each arithetic operation (sum/multiplication/division/remainder/exponentation) has the running time of the fastest known algorithm, independent of the implementation that is actually used (This includes methods that you wrote yourself).

  - Addition can be done in linear time
  - Multiplcation/division/remainder run in \$ O(n \cdot \log(n))\$ where \$n\$ is the sum of the numbers of bits of the inputs <sup>*</sup>.
  - Exponentiation \$N^X\$ runs in \$O((n \log x)(\log(n)+\log(\log x)))\$ where \$n\$ and \$x\$ are the numbers of bits in \$N\$ and \$X\$ respectively.
  - If you know faster algorithms please link them in your challenge
- All built-in base-conversion/library methods for base-conversion are assumed to run in quadratic time in the input, even if the actual implementation is faster
- *(... more rules will follow)*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

---

<sup>*</sup>
The \$O(n log (n)) \$ multiplication algorithm assumes that both arguments have the approximately same size, for simplicity you may assume that the same complexity can be archived for arbitrary argument sizes (this may not be true in practice).

---

## Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is there interest in a challenge of this form?
- Is my explanation clear?

Comment: This seems like it would be extremely hard for languages with no built-in big integers, because they probably have to implement subquadratic multiplication

Comment: @CommandMaster I clarified that the running time of the multiplication method does not matter

Comment: I see. Does it that apply to multiplying by 10 \$a\$ times, or do you have to calculate \$10^a\$ once and then multiply by it?

Comment: @CommandMaster repeated multiplication by fixed number will be calculated as exponentiation, multiplication until a given condition is satisfied will be calculated as individual multiplications

Comment: Is `x` in exponent width or value?

Comment: Need O(nm) multiplication when m>>n

Answer (score 2):

## Implement the "Wolontis" Function

While looking at old ALGOL documentation with someone else on Discord, this "famous" function popped up:

[image: An image claiming to show "the famous Wolontis Function"]

Although it’s mentioned in other language manuals of the era, such as Runcible and FORTRAN, we haven't managed to find any references to this function online — so let's change that.

The expression in the image is \$\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^3}}}\$. Your task is to implement this function for positive inputs, as its value is undefined at \$x=0\$ and imaginary for negative \$x\$. Floating-point inaccuracies are permitted.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

### Sandbox questions

- How accurate/precise should answers be required to be?
- What other tags should I add?
- Any other information I should include? e.g. would a graph be helpful?

Comment: there's references to it [here](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Knuth_Don_X4100/PDF_index/k-6-pdf/k-6-R11-UnivacSS-FORTRANII-prelim-spec.pdf) and [here](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2018/07/102784982-05-01-acc.pdf). I think 'famous' means famous to 1950s mathematicians ^^

Answer (score 2):

## Compute the Kimberling Sequence

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Introduction

The [Kimberling Seqeunce](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KimberlingSequence.html) is a sequence of sequences.
Each sequence is defined in terms of the previous sequence and the previous stage number.
At each stage, the numbers from the previous stage are rearranged as follows:

- For k in [1,...,i], write term i+k and then term i-k.
- Discard the ith term.
- Write the remaining terms in order.

We start with all positive integers at stage 0, so the first few rows look like this.

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
4  2  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
6  2  7  4  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
8  7  9  2 10  6 11 12 13 14 15
```

At each stage, the number on the diagonal is expelled (it is an open question as to whether every number is eventually expelled).

## Challenge

Your program must take a positive integer n as input and output [the integer expelled in forming the nth stage](https://oeis.org/A007063) of the Kimberling sequence.

Answer the following questions for your readers.

Standard loopholes are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 3
3 -> 5
4 -> 4
5 -> 10
6 -> 7
7 -> 15
8 -> 8
9 -> 20
10 -> 9
11 -> 18
12 -> 24
25 -> 2
100 -> 229
1000 -> 394
1001 -> 1274
```

More test cases from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007063/b007063.txt).

### Sandbox Questions

This is my first code golf question, so I'm not sure what to ask other than is there anything that I can improve/need to fix before asking the main site?

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox! I think your initial explanation is a bit imprecise/incorrect. I think you want to say something like: "at stage `k`  write the value from stage `k-1` at index `k+1`, then index `k-1`, then write the rest of the sequence from stage `k-1` excluding the value at index `k`" or something (probably format it better, as you have already). As it is, you don't define `i` or `k`. Also, I think you should consider the default template for [tag:sequence] in the tag info (click "more info" to see it). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I mostly just copied the definition from the MathWorld link, but I'll make it more understandable.

Comment: Darn. I almost finished submitting this question, and then I saw it was a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67542/the-kimberling-sequence

Answer (score 2):

### Generate the snowflake pattern sequence

A snowflake figure looks like this:

[image: 1,2,4,8]

A few rules govern how many points each ring can have.

- The innermost ring must have between 1 and 8 inclusive points.
- Every other ring must have between 2 and 8 inclusive points.
- To ensure symmetry, every ring must have a integer multiple times as many points as the next smallest ring.

Valid snowflake sequences, from the smallest to the largest ring, include: `1,2,2,6`, `2,4,8`, `3,6`, `8,8,8,8,8`, etc.

Your task is, given a number, output the best configuration of rings.

If there are multiple solutions, find the most aesthetically pleasing one as follows:

- The one with the most unique ring sizes
- Unique ring sizes being equal, the one with the biggest smallest ring. Eg. `2,6` is better than `1,7`.
- If the unique ring sizes and smallest ring are both equal, output the one with the smallest total number of rings.

If there are still multiple options, you may choose one arbitrarily.

### Test Cases

| Number | Pattern | Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `1` | [image: 1] |
| 2 | `2` | [image: 2] |
| 3 | `1,2` | [image: 1,2] |
| 4 | `1,3` | [image: 1,3] |
| 5 | `1,4` | [image: 1,4] |
| 6 | `2,4` | [image: 2,4] |
| 7 | `1,2,4` | [image: 1,2,4] |
| 8 | `2,6` | [image: 2,6] |
| 9 | `1,2,6` | [image: 1,2,6] |
| 10 | `1,3,6` | [image: 1,3,6] |
| 11 | `1,2,8` | [image: 1,2,8] |
| 12 | `4,8` | [image: 4,8] |
| 13 | `1,4,8` | [image: 1,4,8] |

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 1,2]
[image: 1,3]
[image: 1,4]
[image: 2,4]
[image: 1,2,4]
[image: 2,6]
[image: 1,2,6]
[image: 1,3,6]
[image: 1,2,8]
[image: 4,8]
[image: 1,4,8]

Answer (score 2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

## Read a French number

We have [Spell out numbers in French](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35435/spell-out-numbers-in-french), [Translate numbers to French](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117737/translate-numbers-to-french) and [Telling time in French](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58738/telling-time-in-french/), but we were missing the reverse:

### Challenge

Read a French expression, and output the corresponding integer.

### Input

In true French, a French number expression is a list of French words separated by whitespace, and possibly by hyphens `"-"` and the word `"et"`, such as `"sept mille deux cent vingt-et-un"`.

For this challenge, you do not need to care about hyphens and the word `"et"`: you are free to take input as a whitespace-separated string of words such as `"sept mille deux cent vingt un"`, or as a list of single-word strings such as `["sept", "mille", "deux", "cent", "vingt", "un"]`.

All French words will be taken from the following list:

```
        'zero': 0, 'un': 1, 'deux': 2, 'trois': 3, 'quatre': 4,
        'cinq': 5, 'six': 6, 'sept': 7, 'huit': 8, 'neuf': 9,
        'dix': 10, 'onze': 11, 'douze': 12, 'treize': 13,
        'quatorze': 14, 'quinze': 15, 'seize': 16,
        'vingt': 20, 'trente': 30, 'quarante': 40, 'cinquante': 50,
        'soixante': 60,
        'cent': 100, 'mille': 1000, 'million': 1000000, 'milliard': 1000000000
```

Note that in correct French, `"million"` and `"milliard"` must take an `-s` in plural form, but for this challenge you do not need to care about that. "zéro" also must take an accent on the "e", but you do not need to care about that. "un" must be "une" in feminine form, but you do not need to care about that.

Also note that if we simply added `"septante: 70, octante: 80, huitante: 80, nonante: 90"` then we would be able to handle Belgian French and Swiss French, but for this challenge you do not need to care about that.

### Output

Output one integer, corresponding to the French input number.

### Conversion rule

Once the sequence of French words has been converted into a sequence of numbers, this sequence can be converted into one number by identifying the largest number in the sequence, then using one simple recurrence rule:

```
convert(left, largest, right) = convert(left) * largest + convert(right)
```

with of course the special cases that `convert(empty left sequence) = 1` and `convert(empty right sequence) = 0`.

For instance:

```
"sept mille deux cent vingt un"
[7    1000  2    100  20    1]
[7] * 1000 + [2 100 20 1]
7000 + ([2] * 100 + [20 1])
7000 + (200 + ([] * 20 + [1]))
7221
```

### Test cases

```
"sept mille deux cent vingt un"     ->  7221
"soixante douze cent vingt un"      ->  7221
"dix sept cent quatre vingt neuf"   ->  1789
"mille sept cent quatre vingt neuf" ->  1789
"trois mille neuf cent quatre vingt dix sept" -> 3997
"cent mille milliard cent trente sept million trois cent quatre vingt quinze mille huit cent cinq"
    ->  100_000_137_395_805
"zero"                 -> 0
"un milliard dix sept" -> 1_000_000_017
"mille"                -> 1000
```

### Rules

- This is code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins!

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement a simple stack language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267442/118045)

Comment: Do you plan to prevent stack based languages just `eval`'ing it? Also, what's the Winning Criteria..? [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @ATaco No, I think `eval` for stack languages would still be interesting. How am I supposed to mark the winning criteria?

Comment: I suggest to represent the stack in a left=bottom/right=top manner, like it is typically done in every stack based language I know.

Comment: »*and push them in the opposite order (swap)*« strictly thought, they are not pushed in the opposite order: A swap pushes the value first that was popped first. But I doubt this will be misunderstood by anyone. (-;

Comment: @Philippos would "and push them so that they are in opposite order" be better? woudln't change it to "and push them in the same order" which would definitely make it more confusing

Comment: Agreed! »opposite order« is the clearest.

Comment: I am *definitely* trying this in Trilangle if/when it's posted. Maybe give me a couple weeks because it's exam week, but

Comment: Would it be allowed to only support integers in some bounded interval (e.g. 32-bit integers), or do you require support for arbitrary size integers? Is the integer format required to be decimal or would unary integers be allowed?

Comment: Can the instructions be represented as a sequence of smaller instructions? Can I for example have an an instruction `#` that pops two numbers and pushes the sum and difference and then define addition as `#drop` and subtraction as `# swap drop` or do all operations have to be atomic

Comment: @bsoelch Bounded integers are fine (but maybe specify if it's a very low bound), and you can input them in whatever way you like. Instructions can be not atomic as long as they're deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

## Parse nested absolute values

[Part1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267296/parse-nested-absolute-values)

[Part2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267297/parse-nested-absolute-values-2)

Comment: Implicit products would definitely lead to some obvious ambiguous cases like `|1|2|3|`. I notice that you do account for ambiguity in the spec; are there any such cases without implicit products? One way or another, the solutions would be radically different, since you can’t just assign a parenthesis direction based on local context.

Answer (score 2):

## [ASCII flood fill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268698/72726)

Answer (score 2):

## Simulate a Plant Cell [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Now posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268553/95204)! (old drafts still in version history)

Comment: The challenge seems good, but the way it's explained/presented could use some improvement. The C6H12O6+6O2 part should be in any order.

Comment: Done and posted

Answer (score 2):

### Generate an efficient A* heuristic [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

A* is a pathfinding algorithm that can be much faster than Dijkstra's, but it requires a heuristic. The heuristic is a function that takes as input one point of the graph, and the destination, then gives a lower bound for the distance between the two points.

The closer the heuristic is to the true shortest distance, the faster the algorithm runs. But if the heuristic ever overestimates, the algorithm is no longer guaranteed to find the shortest path.

Your task is to generate a good heuristic for a given graph. You must submit 2 functions:

- The first functions must run in at most O(n^3) time. Given a graph, output up to three 64-bit floating point numbers per point.
- The second function must run in O(1). Given two points on the graph, output a lower bound for the distance between the two points.

Edges of the graph are guaranteed to have positive, non-zero, integer lengths.

### Scoring

Your score is the sum of the differences of your heuristic and the true shortest distance on the (yet to be decided) large graph below. The smallest score wins.

Comment: I think you meant that if it overestimates the algorithm might not find the shortest path, not underestimate

Comment: Do you want answers to optimize for the particular graph you give, or work well for some general class?

Comment: @CommandMaster I'm looking for a general algorithm but the test case will be just one large graph, which will be the street grid for a real life city, distances scaled by the speed limit. Hard coding the results for that specific graph is a standard loophole but using patterns that may be present is encouraged

Comment: Does the second function only get the numbers for the two points, or can it access the entire graph (and just has to use \$O(1)\$ time)?

Comment: If you take a real life city, does it mean the graph is planer?

Comment: I think it would be better to look at the ratio, not the difference, between the heuristic and the true distance. I also think allowing \$O(\log^k(n))\$ time might allow more interesting solutions

Answer (score 2):

This question was marked as [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269022/) and is therefore not shown - you can see [the revision history](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/26193/revisions) for details.

Comment: Can I use random simulation? If so, how many trials are required? Can I output as a floating point number or a fraction? If you think that `0, 00 => 100%` should be handled, you may want `00, 0 => 0%` too.

Comment: @Bubbler No typical random. Output flexible. I don't place both `X,Y` and `Y,X` in the list

Comment: Suggested test cases: `000, 101 => 41.7% (5/12)`, `000, 011 => 40% (2/5)`, `111, 1001 => 57.1% (4/7)`

Comment: This was going to be Part 2 of my [proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26141).

Comment: An interesting test case is `111`, `0011`; `111` is expected to appear after 14 bits while `0011` is expected to appear after 16 bits... but before `111`!

Comment: @Neil Is it 5/12? I currently don't have a solver

Comment: My source gives 7/12 but I assume that's the probability for `0011`.

Comment: `01`, `1` is a valid test case. You have a 1/2 chance of the first bit being `1`, in which case `1` will appear first, otherwise `01` will appear first. I think `0`, `00` is also a valid test case; `0` always appears first of course.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sum up snail number neighbours](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/270260/72726)

Answer (score 2):

## [Divmod continuosly until the remainder is 1 or 0, then get the remainder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269204/divmod-continuously-until-the-remainder-is-1-or-0-then-get-the-remainder)

Comment: Doesn't `88,7` continue `12,4` and `3,0`, resulting in `0`?

Comment: @Philippos Thanks! Probably it's a typo.

Comment: I liked this challenge!

Comment: @enzo Just a reminder for you: if you see a good post, then you can upvote it, not just commenting it.

Answer (score 2):

[The primitive circle problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269988/the-primitive-circle-problem)

Answer (score 2):

## [Complete a mystery sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269486/complete-a-mystery-sequence)

Given a sequence of three integers, determine if the sequence is arithmetic (of the form `[a, a+d, a+2*d]`) or geometric (of the form `[a, a*r, a*r^2]`) by outputting a fourth term that completes it (`a+3*d` for arithmetic, `a*r^3` for geometric).

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> 4 (This is an arithmetic sequence with a difference of 1)
[2, 4, 8] -> 16 (This is a geometric sequence with a ratio 2)
[20, 15, 10] -> 5 (arithmetic sequence, d=-5)
[6, 6, 6] -> 6 (arithmetic with d=0 OR geometric with r=1)
[3, -9, 27] -> -81 (geometric with r=-3)
```

- Input is guaranteed to be a valid arithmetic and/or geometric sequence (so you won't have to handle something like `[10, 0, 99]`)
- For geometric sequences, the ratio between terms is guaranteed to be an integer (ie. `[4, 6, 9]` would be an invalid input, as the ratio would be 1.5)
- If a sequence could be either arithmetic or geometric, you may output either term that completes it
- This is code golf, so aim for the lowest byte count possible!

---

Notes:

- I'm not sure if there is a sequence that could be completed two different ways. I'd assume there is, but I haven't found it (although I haven't been looking for very long)
- Is this too much of an A/B challenge?
- Title suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I think it's fine. Maybe you can just call it a "mathematical progression" instead of "mystery sequence", to recall [AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and [GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), but it's just my opinion

Comment: Some minor things to be added: 1. you need to define a scoring method (it usually is [code-golf], fewer bytes better) and 2. maybe change the wording "determine if a sequence is ... and output a fourth term that completes it" to "determine if a sequence is ... by outputting a fourth term that completes it", because the former makes it look like there are two outputs instead of just one. Again, it's just an opinion of mine, it's fine either way

Comment: You should consider adding some info on how to handle invalid input (e.g. [10, 0, 99]): does the answerers need to validate the input first, outputting some value such as "not valid"? Or they can assume that only valid input will be passed (recommended)?

Comment: That all said, you made a very interesting question! Keep going.

Comment: @enzo thank you for the input! i'll try and make some of the points clearer

Comment: 'd like to see if solution use no branch

Comment: @l4m2 I almost have one, but it fails on a constant sequence. It might be a bit of an annoying edge-case, seeing as no other sequence can be both geometric and arithmetic

Comment: Is `[1, 0, 0]` (geometric with ratio `0`) a possible sequence?

Comment: @CommandMaster Saw similar question but three inputs are all positive so they did `c%b?2*c-b:c*c/b`

Answer (score 2):

## How many people are awake?

The following data contains the population of each timezone in the world ([source](https://observablehq.com/@mattdzugan/population-by-time-zone-creating-a-dataset)):

```
UTC;Population (in thousands)
-11;57
-10;1853
-9.5;8
-9;639
-8;66121
-7;41542
-6;272974
-5;332101
-4.5;31923
-4;77707
-3.5;499
-3;248013
-2;4855
-1;3285
0;285534
+1;857443
+2;609921
+3;496279
+3.5;81889
+4;129089
+4.5;31042
+5;305642
+5.5;1458945
+6;199668
+6.5;50112
+7;439650
+8;1679526
+9;220112
+9.5;1814
+10;29482
+11;5267
+11.5;2
+12;6112
+13;308
+14;11
```

(for the sake of simplicity, I'm removing `+X.75` UTC times from the list)

Assuming that every person in the world wakes up at 8AM and goes to sleep at 12AM (in their local time), how many people are simultaneously awake in the world at a given UTC time?

For example, suppose the given time is 2PM UTC. These are the timezones where the local time at 2PM UTC is between 8AM inclusive and 12AM exclusive:

```
  -6 08:00 272974
  -5 09:00 332101
-4.5 09:30 31923
  -4 10:00 77707
-3.5 10:30 499
  -3 11:00 248013
  -2 12:00 4855
  -1 13:00 3285
  +0 14:00 285534
  +1 15:00 857443
  +2 16:00 609921
  +3 17:00 496279
+3.5 17:30 81889
  +4 18:00 129089
+4.5 18:30 31042
  +5 19:00 305642
+5.5 19:30 1458945
  +6 20:00 199668
+6.5 20:30 50112
  +7 21:00 439650
  +8 22:00 1679526
  +9 23:00 220112
+9.5 23:30 1814
```

Now, just add the population of these timezones and output 7818023 (corresponding to ~7.8 billion people).

### Input

An UTC time. You may accept one of the following (or all of them):

- two natural numbers ***h*** and ***m***, where ***0 ≤ h ≤ 23*** and ***m ∈ {0, 30}***
- a real number ***r***, where ***0 ≤ r < 24*** and its fractional part can be only 0 or 5 (so ***r = 23.5*** corresponds to 23:30).

[Standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/91472) applies, so you can accept them as lists, strings, etc. You can even accept ***m*** as a boolean value, where 0 means `HH:00` and 1 means `HH:30`.

There are two ways of solving this question: hardcoding the output (since there are only 48 possible inputs) or hardcoding the population data and solving by time arithmetic. However, to make this challenge more interesting, you are allowed to accept the population data as an additional input, so you don't need to hardcode it (thus saving you some bytes) and focusing only on the time arithmetic. So you can read it as additional lines from STDIN or an additional function argument.

### Output

How many people are awake at the given time, in thousands.

#### Test cases

```
00:00 -> 1942634
00:30 -> 1942634
01:00 -> 2382284
01:30 -> 2432396
02:00 -> 2632064
02:30 -> 4091009
03:00 -> 4396651
03:30 -> 4427693
04:00 -> 4556782
04:30 -> 4638671
05:00 -> 5134950
05:30 -> 5134950
06:00 -> 5744871
06:30 -> 5744871
07:00 -> 6602314
07:30 -> 6602314
08:00 -> 6887848
08:30 -> 6887848
09:00 -> 6891133
09:30 -> 6891133
10:00 -> 6895977
10:30 -> 6895977
11:00 -> 7143682
11:30 -> 7144181
12:00 -> 7215776
12:30 -> 7247697
13:00 -> 7574531
13:30 -> 7574531
14:00 -> 7818023
14:30 -> 7816209
15:00 -> 7637639
15:30 -> 7637639
16:00 -> 6024234
16:30 -> 6024234
17:00 -> 5585223
17:30 -> 5535119
18:00 -> 5337304
18:30 -> 3878359
19:00 -> 3572774
19:30 -> 3541732
20:00 -> 3412643
20:30 -> 3330754
21:00 -> 2834475
21:30 -> 2834475
22:00 -> 2224554
22:30 -> 2224554
23:00 -> 1367111
23:30 -> 1367111
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)

Answer (score 2):

## Accumulate spare change

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[currency](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency)

---

In this challenge, given some cash, you'll pay for various items as simply as possible (e.g., one $20 bill for a $17 purchase), and get spare change in return. Your task is to figure out what bills and coins you have after all of the transactions.

#### Input

Your input will be an initial amount of cash, and a list of zero or more prices of items. You can take these either as dollars with decimal cents ($12.95 = `12.95`) or as an integer number of cents ($12.95 = `1295`). The prices of items will not exceed the initial amount of cash, and no inputs will contain fractional cents.

#### Task

First, you'll break down your inputted cash into bills and coins, such that the minimum number of bills/coins are required. The following bills and coins exist:

- $100
- $50
- $20
- $10
- $5
- $1
- $0.25
- $0.10
- $0.05
- $0.01

Then, for each item purchased, you'll pay using the fewest bills/coins possible, and you'll get change in return. If there are multiple possibilities (e.g., for $45, you could pay with a $50 or a $100), choose the closest one. The only exception is if it's possible to pay using 2-4 of the same bill/coin instead of one that's larger than doing it that way (e.g., $40 as 2 $20 bills, or $1 as 4 $0.25 coins if a $1 bill isn't available, but never 4 $5 bills instead of one $20 bill).

#### Output

Your output will be the number of each bill and coin remaining after the transactions are complete.

#### Example

**Initial cash:** $70

You now have $50 + $20.

**Transactions:**

- $11: You pay with $20, and now have $50 + $5 + $1 × 4
- $0.65: You pay with $1, and now have $50 + $5 + $1 × 3 + $0.25 + $0.10
- $18.75: You pay with $50, and now have $20 + $10 + $5 + $1 × 2 + $0.25 × 2 + $0.10
- $25: You pay with $20 + $5, and now have $10 + $1 × 2 + $0.25 × 2 + $0.10
- $2: You pay with $1 × 2, and now have $10 + $0.25 × 2 + $0.10
- $4.25: You pay with $10, and now have $5 + $0.25 × 5 + $0.10
- $1: You pay with $0.25 × 4, and now have $5 + $0.25 + $0.10

**Output:** $5 + $0.10

Comment: I like it a lot because there are a real-world applications. At the final step in the example, you _"now have $5 + $0.25 + $0.10"_. Shouldn't the output be that instead of "$5 + $0.10"?

Comment: Possible clarification: _"than doing it that way (e.g., $40 as 2 $20 bills, or $1 as 4 $0.25 coins if a $1 bill isn't available, …_" → "then use the smaller denomination (e.g., $40 as 2 $20 bills instead of a $50 bill, or $1 as 4 $0.25 coins instead of a $5 bill when a $1 bill isn't available, …"

Comment: Is there a "black box" issue? The output will in many cases be the same regardless of how you handle the transactions. An answer that disregards the rules may still show the expected result for many inputs — e.g., if you just subtract the total transactions from the initial cash and break down the result into allowed denominations, you probably get the right output much of the time. Proposal: make the test case enforce "the only exception" rule. Or ask that an answer should show the intermediate steps. The rules would be easier to refer to if they were in a numbered list.

Comment: @doubleunary No, that won't give you the right answer. If I have two $100s and deduct $4.16 a few dozen times, I accumulate tons of pennies. Simply taking the remaining cash and making chasnge with it would give you a totally wrong result, and that's the main point of the challenge

Comment: Thats understood, but the _"output will in many cases be the same"_. The test case in the question would be vulnerable to this shortcut. I suggest you modify the test case or request intermediate steps be shown. It is also unclear whether "the only exception" rule would be observed when calculating the denominations you get as change. It would be good to specify explicitly how change is calculated.

Comment: @doubleunary I'll have more test cases in the final challenge yeah

Comment: Great. I left a couple other comments as well. Perhaps you could edit the sandbox question to its final form so that others could review those edits before you post the question on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

## How quickly can you type this string?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given a string consisting of only printable ascii (letters, numbers, symbols, and spaces), how many keystrokes are required minimally to type out this string from scratch? The allowed keystrokes are:

- one character from printable ascii for 1 keystroke
- <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (copy) any contiguous substring you have typed so far and replace whatever is currently copied (2 keystrokes) and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> (paste) any string in your clipboard (1 keystroke)
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> the last typed character for 1 keystroke

For example, the string "cbaabcbabaacba" can be typed in 12 keystrokes, which is optimal.

### Test Cases

```
cbaabcbabaacba => 12
ababcc => 6
aaaaaaaaaaaaa => 9
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: The common definition of _key stroke_ in typing competitions is _each key press_. Thus you must count <kbd>⇧</kbd> (shift), too. From your description it is unclear what <kbd>Ctrl‑C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl‑V</kbd> mean. As a terminal user I’d say `ETX` and `SYN` respectively.

Comment: Ctrl C and Ctrl V and copy and paste, respectively.

Comment: Does Ctrl-C append to the clipboard, or reset it?

Comment: It could be either, I'm not sure which would be best for the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Fastest bytewise comparisons in 64-bit unsigned integers

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [bitwise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitwise) [tag:i-don't-know]

- Create a function that accepts two 64-bit unsigned integers, `a` and
  `b`.
- Compare each corresponding byte in `a` and `b`.
- If the byte in `a` is greater than the byte in `b` in the same position, set the
  corresponding byte in the output to `255`.
- Otherwise, set the corresponding byte in the output to `0`.
- Return the resulting 64-bit unsigned integer.

Restrictions: the code runs in x86-64, no explict SSEx, AVXx (is ok if the compiler vectorices the result)

Example:

```
a =      202      141        1      123       61       53       40 251
b =      158       75      185      217        5       90      152 225
a = 11001010 10001101 00000001 01111011 00111101 00110101 00101000 11111011
b = 10011110 01001011 10111001 11011001 00000101 01011010 10011000 11100001
a>b=     255      255        0        0      255        0        0      255
a>b=11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000 11111111
```

Comment: [GCC compiles it to a single instruction](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y8TsYb59f) so it seems bad

Comment: @l4m2 I see, is SSE. What about non using bytes, like using numbers with `4 bits`, `5 bits`, `9 bits`

Comment: @l4m2 The compiler using SSE means that `64 bit` registers (non SIMD) remain unused,  so there is an opportunity to extract more performance, although I don't know how to take advantage of it. By the way, without compiler optimizations, your code does unnecessary branches. If you store `0,1` in each byte, `C[i] = A[i] > B[i]`, and at the end return the `C*255`, you avoid a lot of `?`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swap letter cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/270235/swap-letter-cases)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Why isn't this a dupe yet lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Reconstruct a list from its prefixes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271430/reconstruct-a-list-from-its-prefixes)

Answer (score 2):

## [How quickly can you type this unary string?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271793/how-quickly-can-you-type-this-unary-string)

Comment: Can there be multiple strings in the clipboard or only one at a time?

Comment: @CommandMaster Only one.

Comment: Isn't ctrl-c technically two keystrokes?

Comment: You can't erase characters, right?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes.

Comment: @vengy For the sake of simplicity it's one in this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swifty Argument Labels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/272116/118665)

Comment: So empty input just behave as `_`

Comment: @l4m2 Yeah, pretty much. I should probably simplify that... gimme a sec to edit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Implement a 2-player version of 1D Chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/272110/implement-a-2-player-version-of-1d-chess)

Comment: Your question had 4 out of 5 reopen votes, but I thought of a bunch of other questions about game over. I've seen less well developed questions go live on the main site, but it's good to get things as clear as possible. Any reason why you've deleted the title? I would suggest maybe include in the title that you're looking for a 2 player game, as that seemed to be creating some confusion. For inspiration, see the regular 2 dimensional chess question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45179/15599

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I've added the title, other than that, i''m not sure what else there is to improve

Comment: Per my last comment on the original question consider the following. Incorrect moves: presumably the program must disallow ending your move in check? Also what game-over behaviour is required. You've noted that according to chess rules the game ends when there are only the kings left or a stalemate/checkmate is reached. Is the program required to exit when this condition is reached (in particular stalemate/checkmate requires checking if a player is able to move) or can it just hang?

Comment: Feedback here in the sandbox can be useful, but it doesn't get the same traffic as on the main site, so some things can get missed even here. You were doing pretty well for a first question.

Comment: Also, maybe limit input format to START CELL, END CELL. The PIECE, END CELL format actually raises several questions about whether a player should use uppercase, lowercase, or case according to their colour. Apologies for suggesting it in the first place.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt i seem to have addressed everything you've talked about. no worries about suggesting the PIECE, END CELL format, it's more readable

Comment: Program must also exit when there are only kings left? Also I suggest you delete the bit about 3-move-repitition rule being "welcome." I don't recommend requiring it (very tedious to implement) and nobody is going to do if if you don't require it. Other than that, now that you have deleted from the main site and posted to sandbox, I suggest you wait a few days and see if anyone thinks of anything else.

Comment: Could you specify better the "Incorrect moves must be rejected" rule? Do you mean that the program should detect illegal moves and ask for input again, or could a program exit with an error when a player tries an illegal move? 
It could also be an idea to just let programs assume that all input will be legal and save people from having to validate input every time, but it is your choice what to require here.

Comment: @Leo i've hopefully clarified it

Answer (score 2):

Comment: Maybe add test cases with the words title-cased? And even with mOrE eRrAtIc CaPs, unless it's more to the point to guarantee that the input will always be either all-lower, all-upper, or title.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I am not going to do title case.  I've considered it and I think it adds to much complexity, plus there are a bunch of cases where I don't even know what's proper, (m'Ubh, M'ubh, or M'Ubh?)  And I definitely am not doing erratic caps.

Answer (score 1):

### I've Got The Key, I've Got The Secret

A cryptography challenge in 2 parts.

### Part 1

Implement a pair of programs in any language (the two programs could be in different languages if you wanted) to encode and decode a string of plaintext.

### Input and Output

The encoder must take the plaintext (and an optional key) and return an encoded string.
The decoder must take the cyphertext (and an optional key) and return the plaintext exactly as it was given to the encoder.

### Restrictions

- The encoding and decoding code must be entirely implemented in the language - no libraries or cryptography functions may be used.
- The code (encoder+decoder) cannot be longer than 1024 characters.

### Part 2

Implement programs (multiple programs per answer, one answer per entrant) which crack your opponents encryption algorithms.

### Input

The cyphertext.

### Output

The plaintext that generated the ciphertext.

### Scoring

I will upvote all answers to part 1 which have working encryption and have obviously made an attempt at golfing their answer.

In order to be eligible to win, an entrant will have to have taken part in both parts of the question. Overall score will be (length of shortest program that cracks your code-(length of encoder+length of decoder)). Highest score wins and winning entrant's entries will be accepted on both questions.

Comment: The obvious place for this to fall flat on its face is if someone is able to implement AES or something similar within the 1024 character restriction.

Comment: Probably better if the methods of the part one programs are disclosed in non-obfuscated language, though with the short length restriction this may not be necessary.

Comment: Forget AES: RSA is easily doable. That aside, you need to define "crack" in part 2.

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether "optional key" means that it's optional to make the algorithm unkeyed (doesn't make much sense, I admit) or optional to supply it, in which case it uses a default key.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just put optional in to leave it up to the implementer whether or not they wanted to have the key input or hard-coded (or use no key). I'd have thought everyone would have the key input into their program, but I didn't want anyone to feel forced into it by the spec. Hmm, if RSA is doable within the character restriction I'll end up with a load of unbreakable codes which would make for a pretty crap part 2. By crack I meant cyphertext goes in, some time later plaintext comes out. Would restricting the character count further help, or is this question beyond help?

Comment: On that definition of crack, I can brute force for the length of the decoder plus a few bytes to iterate over all keys of the right length and some heuristics to check plausibility of the plaintext. The brute force cracker might even be shorter than the decoder if the decoder wasn't written in GolfScript... I think this question may be beyond help.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Okay, thanks. I like the 'build your own - knock everyone else's down' aspect of this question though. I'll have to find another area where it could apply.

Comment: @Gareth I too like the competitive nature of this idea. I'm looking forward to a question with this plan in mind!

Comment: I think it would be better to split this into a "cops" post and a "robbers" post.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Wow, this is another blast from the past. I think this pre-dates the cops-and-robbers tag. I always seem to be ahead of my time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Countability of Sets of Finite Sets

The aim of this challenge is to code-golf a program which returns an iterator that will iterate over all possible non-empty finite sets of positive integers.

So if running long enough, this iterator should eventually touch on {1}, {2, 5}, {3, 6, 112} (ie none of these should occur "at infinity")

You may choose the order in which you iterate over these sets, but the order must satisfy the following requirement:

Under a particular ordering, if S is the i'th set to be returned by the iterator, then we shall call i the index of set S.

Let a restriction (k,T) be an assertion about a set S that says S has size k and T is a subset of S.

For a given restriction (k,T) and iterator IT, let the restricted iterator be the iterator which takes sets returned by IT and filters out sets that don't satisfy the assertion, iterating only over the ones that do.  In other words, if IT iterates over the sequence of all sets, the restricted iterator iterates over the subsequence satisfying (k,T).  Now if S is the n'th set returned by the restricted iterator, then we'll call n the restricted index of S with respect to (k,T)

Your ordering must satisfy the property that for any restriction there exists a polynomial P(x) such that for any set satisfying the restriction (with index i and restricted index n), i < P(n)

Note that the following ordering is not acceptable:

{1} {2} {1, 2} {3} {1, 3} {2, 3} {1, 2, 3} {4} {1, 4} {2, 4}...

This is the sequence that comes from counting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... and listing the set bits in the binary representation of each number.

This is because the restriction (1, {}) satisfies only the sets {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}... whose index i as a function of their restricted index is i=2^(n-1) which is not bounded by any polynomial

---

### Sandbox Questions

The reason for the strange requirement at the end is to disqualify any variants on the most natural ordering which simply counts upwards from 1 and enumerates the set bits in each number.  In this ordering, the n'th set of length-one occurs at index 2^n which is non-polynomial.

I posted this problem originally, but didn't think of the obvious solution and so I left out the final restriction.  I'd like to re-post it with the extra restriction.  But first I'd like to know what people think.  Is there a better way I can word that restriction or a more natural restriction I could impose instead?

Comment: I don't understand the extra restriction, so I can't suggest a rewording, but I can say that it needs one. (In particular: what is k? And what function does T serve? Is it really a parameter of the property?)

Comment: I don't understand it either. Maybe a sample of an ordering, satisfying the requirement, and another one, violating it, would help.

Comment: I understand the restriction now, although I haven't worked through the full implications. Does allowing T to be non-empty make a significant difference at all?

Comment: I don't know.  It may not.  I guess the size part is the important part.  I was just thinking that the ordering should be such that you run into all kinds of sets frequently.

Answer (score 1):

### The One with Two Parts

The aim of this challenge is to create a pair of functions which scramble and unscramble any given piece of text.

**Part 1**

In part one you post your scrambling function, along with the length in characters and language of your unscrambling function (but NOT its code). The length of the scrambler does not affect your score so you needn't golf it unless you want to. The two functions may be written in different languages if you wish.

**Input/Output**

The scrambling function should take one argument only - a string containing the input text - and return a string containing the scrambled text. The unscrambling function should also take only one argument - the scrambled text - and return the original text. The input text will be limited to characters in the ASCII set range from 0 to 127.

**Part 2**

In part two you try to beat your opponents' scores for their unscrambling functions. You MUST use the language they specify for their unscrambler in part one. Please give just one answer to this question containing all your unscrambling functions making it clear which question in part one each function unscrambles (maybe each answer in part one should give its scrambler a name for identification?).

Once the closing date (TBA) has passed all participants should post their unscrambling functions in their answer to part one to prove the length, language and functionality of their function.

**Scoring**
The participants score will be calculated as follows: (unscrambler length from part one) - (shortest unscrambler length from part two). The participant with the lowest score wins and will have their answers accepted on both parts of the challenge. To be eligible to win a participant must have taken part in both parts of the question.

*Example*

In part 1:

- Bob posts a Python answer and says his unscrambler is a 165 character Python function.
- Fred posts a GolfScript answer and says his unscrambler is a 59 character GolfScript function.
- Joe posts a JavaScript answer and says his unscrambler is a 180 character PHP function.
- Jim posts a Ruby answer and says his unscrambler is 163 character Ruby function.

In part 2:

- Bob posts an 82 character GolfScript function to unscramble Fred's scrambled text. He also posts a 175 character PHP function to unscramble Joe's scrambled text.
- Fred posts a 181 character PHP function to unscramble Joe's scrambled text.
- Joe posts a 150 character Python function to unscramble Bob's scrambled text.
- Jim posts a 156 character Python function to unscramble Bob's scrambled text. He also posts a 91 character GolfScript function to unscramble Fred's scrambled text.

The scores:

- Bob scores 165 - 150 = 15
- Fred scores 59 - 82 = -23
- Joe scores 180 - 175 = 5
- Jim scores 163 - 0 = 163

so Fred wins.

**Miscellaneous**

I suggest that the closing date be two weeks after the challenge begins, and that unscramblers be posted to part one within 48 hours of closing date in order to be eligible.

Comment: Are there any rules regarding scrambling? i.e. is "Stockholm"->"Stockhoml" a valid scramble? (it may not matter, but I'm curious. And to be clear, the scoring is the difference between your opponent's unscrambler length and your own for the same language?

Comment: @Gaffi No, you scramble however you want. If you want to just output the text as given that's ok, but you probably won't win with that strategy. The aim is to do it in a way that is easy for you to unscramble but difficult for all the others. That way your score will be smaller. Yes, the score is the difference between your score and the score of the best of your opponents' attempts. I'll add an example to make that bit clearer I think.

Comment: I think this gives an advantage to people who use (relatively) obscure languages. If the scrambler is written in J and the descrambler in GolfScript then only people who know both can realistically attempt a descrambler. (NB the rules don't say how the score works if no-one attempts a particular unscrambler).

Comment: I did consider saying that programs that had no attempts at beating them were not eligible to win, but then I thought that if they were scored as though the shortest attempt to beat them was 0 then they wouldn't have much of an advantage. I'll add that into the example scoring. What do you think? I want to encourage answers that are clever or well obfuscated rather than written in Malbolge or something like that.

Comment: Does it mean that since no one attempts to solve Jim's Ruby challenge his chances are minimal that he'll win? That would discourage complicated scramblers or difficult languages.

Comment: @Howard As it stands, yes that's how it would work. The alternative, as Peter Taylor points out, is that people using obscure languages have an advantage. I'm not sure how else I might score unscramblers that no-one has attempted to beat. Maybe give them a score of 0? Please, if you or anyone else has any suggestions for making the challenge as inclusive as possible, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

### Compile BF to TM

Your task is to write a compiler accepting a Brainfuck program (previous challenge: [Interpret Brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck), wikipedia: [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)) as input and outputting a Turing Machine which produces identical output when supplied with the same (correct) input.

You may select the output format from among the various formats accepted by the answers to [Turing Machine Simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/turing-machine-simulator).

The following links may also be useful.
[An introduction to programming in BF](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf_intro.html)
[BF is Turing-complete](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf_Turing.html)
[Programming a Turing Machine](http://www.earlham.edu/~peters/courses/logsys/turing.htm)
[Programming Praxis: Turing Machine Simulator](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/03/27/a-turing-machine-simulator/)

Equivalently, you may write a Brainfuck interpreter in TM, or any partial compilation/interpretation which results in a TM program as described above.

If we consider squares of the TM tape to represent bits (blank=0, mark=1) of the BF memory, then eight squares represent a cell. Each BF instruction translates to a minimum of 8 states of the Turing Machine.

'>' "advance" (++ptr) could be implemented by eight states (sixteen transitions):

```
adv8 _ adv7 R _
adv8 1 adv7 R 1
adv7 _ adv6 R _
adv7 1 adv6 R 1
adv6 _ adv5 R _
adv6 1 adv5 R 1
adv5 _ adv4 R _
adv5 1 adv4 R 1
adv4 _ adv3 R _
adv4 1 adv3 R 1
adv3 _ adv2 R _
adv3 1 adv2 R 1
adv2 _ adv1 R _
adv2 1 adv1 R 1
adv1 _ link R _
adv1 1 link R 1
```

where 'link' represents the first state of the following instruction.

'<' "rewind" (--ptr) can be implemented similarly by making leftward movements and rewriting the same symbol just read.

'+' "increment" (++*ptr) can be implemented by a ripple-carry from the Least Significant Bit to the Most Significant Bit, borrowing "rewind" states to back-up to *normal* position. If the LSB is on the left, it would look something like this:

```
inc8 _ link N 1
inc8 1 inc7 R _
inc7 _ rew1 N 1
inc7 1 inc6 R _
inc6 _ rew2 N 1
inc6 1 inc5 R _
inc5 _ rew3 N 1
inc5 1 inc4 R _
inc4 _ rew4 N 1
inc4 1 inc3 R _
inc3 _ rew5 N 1
inc3 1 inc2 R _
inc2 _ rew6 N 1
inc2 1 inc1 R _
inc1 _ rew7 N 1
inc1 1 overflow N 1
```

where *overflow* is a HALT state.

For I/O, the simplest way I can think is to place all input on the tape after the memory area, and expand the alphabet to include a symbol indicating the dividing line between the memory portion and the input portion of the tape. In fact, by expanding the cell size to nine squares, this symbol can serve as an input *pointer*, advancing as the input is consumed. (So "advance" and "rewind" now need 9 states each.) And another new symbol is written in front of the current memory cell to serve as the memory pointer. Inputting a byte therefore consists of schleping each bit over the entire space between the two tape positions with something like this:

```
input _ set-memptr L _
input 1 set-memptr L 1
set-memptr _ find-inptr R *
find-inptr _ find-inptr R _
find-inptr 1 find-inptr R 1
find-inptr $ schlep-bit R $
schlep-bit _ schlep-blank L _
schlep-bit 1 schlep-one L 1
schlep-blank $ schlep-blank L $
schlep-blank _ schlep-blank L _
schlep-blank 1 schlep-blank L 1
schlep-blank * deposit-blank R *
schlep-one $ schlep-one L $
schlep-one _ schlep-one L _
schlep-one 1 schlep-one L 1
schlep-one * deposit-one R *
deposit-blank _ etc R _
deposit-blank 1 etc R _
deposit-one _ etc R 1
deposit-one 1 etc R 1
```

where "etc" represents going to get the next bit in similar fashion.

To perform a loop (all BF loops are "while" loops, so the exit control is at the beginning and the end has a simple goto back to the beginning), we need first to check is the current cell is zero,

```
zero8 _ zero7 R _
zero8 1 body R 1
zero7 _ zero6 R _
zero7 1 left1 L 1
zero6 _ zero5 R _
zero6 1 left2 L 1
zero5 _ zero4 R _
zero5 1 left3 L 1
zero4 _ zero3 R _
zero4 1 left4 L 1
zero3 _ zero2 R _
zero3 1 left5 L 1
zero2 _ zero1 R _
zero2 1 left6 L 1
zero1 _ exit-loop R _
zero1 1 left7 L 1
left7 _ left6 L _
left7 1 left6 L 1
left6 _ left5 L _
left6 1 left5 L 1
left5 _ left4 L _
left5 1 left4 L 1
left4 _ left3 L _
left4 1 left3 L 1
left4 _ left3 L _
left4 1 left3 L 1
left3 _ left2 L _
left3 1 left2 L 1
left2 _ left1 L _
left2 1 left1 L 1
left2 _ loop-body L _
left2 1 loop-body L 1
...
loop-body-final _ zero8 N _
loop-body-final 1 zero8 N 1
```

So assuming the machine starts at tape-location 0, and the input is on the tape starting at 0 and going to the right,  the "startup code" for this arrangement would be

```
startup _ place$ L _
startup 1 place$ L 1
place$ _ left270000 L $
left270000 _ left269999 L _
...
```

Jeez! The output is going to be ***HUGE!*** It might be better to treat the BF memory as negative-indexed and reverse all the _L_s and _R_s in 'advance', 'rewind', 'increment', and 'decrement'.

---

Questions:

Bonuses for optimizations? If I can implement this myself and provide a complete example output, The bonus could be "subtract the difference between your program's output for the example input with the example output". So eliminating states would be far more valuable than shrinking the code. One could possibly achieve a negative score!

---

*Edit:* Actually I think this is unreasonable unless the Turing Machine is augmented with non-reading (movement-only or epsilon) transitions. Duplicating every letter of the alphabet just to move over one square is just ridiculously painful. That means this challenge won't link-up nicely with the other one. :(

What about, instead of implementing the compiler, just devise a translation scheme (as above) that leads to a smaller output for a trivial sample program (based on calculating, rather than coding)? "Back of the envelope" compiler.

Comment: *"How much detail on BF do I need to supply? Can I simply reference the BF question?"* A link to almost any site that describes the language will do.

Comment: Winning condition?

Comment: "Longest prefix containing syntactically-correct Malbolge!" :) ... I'd say have none at all. Perhaps the questioner should be required to accept their own example answer?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Apologies for my last comment. I thought we were on my other answer about the [fun] tag. . . . This one would be a golf: shortest code by character count. But I think a clever system of bonuses could make it interesting.

Comment: The "Equivalently, you may write a Brainfuck interpreter in TM" option doesn't play very well with being a code golf - how are you going to count the length of the TM?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Since the TM question specified 5-tuples, I think it's sufficient to count the tuples (== transitions). You can reduce states by increasing the alphabet (or vice versa), but the transitions would remain constant, I think.

Comment: I'd like to adopt (work on and post) this challenge if you don't want to. Would I be able to? If you do not respond to this message within two weeks, by community guidelines, I am allowed to take it over.

Comment: Yes, please. If you can do something with it, strike while the iron is hot.

Answer (score 1):

## Graphical Output -- Esoteric Artifacts -- The Glass Bead Game

### Draw the Cabalistic Tree of Life

Simply described, the Tree of Life is an undirected network of nodes representing the conduit between matter and higher forms of spiritual energy. It has an upper face arranged in a hexagon, and a lower fact built from equilateral triangles adjacent to the lower two edges of the upper face. Don't label the paths, paths may overlap however you wish, may be single (thick) lines, even. Code Golf. Bonus -100 for labels on the Sephiroth (nodes); Bonus -150 for Hebrew labels.

[image: Tree of Life after Kirtcher]

### Draw a Mandala for each Natural Number

Draw a circle with interesting visual patterns using the input N [ 1 .. \inf ) to determine the number of points around the circle to anchor figures whose shape is also modified by the input N. Actually, 12 seems like a good max: they're pretty much a blur after that no matter what.

Eg. http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=ve6a.ps
//lotsoflines n = 1 ..12

[image: Mandalas 1 - 12]

(doesn't need to be this elaborate, This is >600 lines of showing-off.).

*. . . need good images for these . . .*

### Draw the Ptolemeic System of the Universe

All the stuff I could find is animated already. Maybe this one's done-to-death. :(

**Update:** Found good stuff on [Alchemy](http://www.alchemywebsite.com/amcl_astronomical_material.html). The "Keplar Platonic" model could be fun (3D and all). [This one](http://www.alchemywebsite.com/emblems/embl317.html) looks good, too. [And this](http://www.alchemywebsite.com/emblems/embl337.html).

### Draw the Pythagorean Monochord

aka pre-classical nomogram. *I misplaced my Pythagoras books, I know I've got a picture somewhere.*

This is [the one I was thinking of](http://www.celestialmonochord.org/log/images/celestial_monochord.jpg).

But I think [this one's even cooler](http://www.sacredscience.com/archive/WortmannDiagrams_files/image189.jpg)

### Draw the I-Ching Hexagrams in King Wen Sequence.

- [King Wen sequence -- Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Wen_sequence)
- [some nice info and images](http://www.biroco.com/yijing/sequence.htm)

I suppose I need to implement this first to avoid copyright issues! :)

Comment: The I-Ching one would have to be in standard order to be remotely interesting, and then becomes as much about [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] as [tag:graphical-output]

Comment: For the others: images, please!

Comment: I've emailed the owner of the Alchemy pages asking for permission to use his copyrighted images. Awaiting response.

Answer (score 1):

### Self-Golfing Code?

I don't know if I just didn't search hard enough, but I couldn't find any challenge regarding self-golfing code, or rather, any code that can deterministically reduce another set of text code to a much smaller program, yet still compile/run.

For example, take this:

```
int main() {
std::cout<<"Hello world 1!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Hello world 2!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Hello world 3!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Hello world 4!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Hello world 5!"<<std::endl;
}
```

And output this (*as one possible solution*):

```
#define A std::cout<<"Hello world 
#define B !"<<std::endl;
#define C B A
int main() {
A 1 C 2 C 3 C 4 C 5 B
}
```

Alternative:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim aNumber As Integer
Dim someString As String
aNumber = 123
someString = "abc"
MsgBox aNumber
MsgBox someString
End Sub
```

into (*again, as one possible solution*)

```
Sub m()
Dim a As Integer
Dim s As String
a = 123
s = "abc"
MsgBox a
MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Do we have a challenge for this?

If not, here are some rules I envision:

- Golfing code need not be in the same language as code to be golfed.
- Since compilers/running of code varies, newly golfed code must still run under same environment.
- Possible challenge scoring (multiple options -- thinking code golf):

  - 1: Shortest golfing code wins (not my favorite, since you can minimally shorten the base code, yet still write the shortest program).
  - 2: Shortest output of a set of pre-defined code (potentially limiting if participants are unfamiliar with the options available)
  - 3: Combination of length of golfing code and the output result of the same as input. (Ratio, summation, etc.) -- This I think is my preferred option.
  - 4: **Multi-player** Ratio of golfed size of other participants' own code versus their original submission. (Similar limitations to that of point #2.)

Comment: Sounds more like an auto-golfer than obfuscation. Seems like it would be very hard to make it a fair contest unless you pick a language to golf, and even then it had better be a simple language (no platform dependency issues or compiler options).

Comment: @PeterTaylor My examples are golfing, but either would work. Perhaps golfing would be simpler, then? I agree that the options for usable languages makes this a bit messy... Would one challenge per language be acceptable? (i.e. aligned with most challenges that are language-agnostic)

Comment: Language-agnostic to mean means that you can write a program to do it in any language. Since the language to be golfed can be different from the submitted program, I don't see any incompatibility between making the problem "Write a program to golf Piet" and being language-agnostic.

Comment: @PeterTaylor So then you see no problem with one question per language on which to operate? Are there any proposed scoring algorithms you particularly like/dislike?

Comment: That depends on what you mean. If you're planning to post 10 questions at once, yes, that would be a problem. But I don't see a problem with posting a well-defined "Auto-golf Piet" and following it up two months later with "Auto-golf Perl 5".

Comment: Scoring is an issue. The halting problem means that it's impossible to write an optimal solution, so the scoring must take into account how good the solution is. I think option 3 is the best, and you'll want a big test set (maybe a few kB taken from a real-world open source project) with coverage of the language features.

Comment: Btw, your first example doesn't work. You can't have unmatched quotes in preprocessor directives. Don't know why.

Comment: I honestly think this would be fine if you did something like solely maco-golfing, making it somewhat language agnostic because of `gcc -E`.

Answer (score 1):

### DeCSS

It is known that the DVD Content Scrambling System can be deciphered with a [rather short program](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/DeCSS/Gallery/) (434 bytes of C, 472 bytes of Perl). Can you do better?

<< Test cases go here >>

---

I don't plan to include a more detailed spec, because it will just wind up duplicating some of the code. The test cases would be in the form of (key, link to data file, md5sum of the deciphered stream).

Comment: And the winning criterion is who is the first to get post from the courts?

Comment: @celtschk, I think that would be unfair. Winning criteria shouldn't really depend on where people live...

Comment: I think you should at least explain the general concept of the spec.

Comment: This actually sounds interesting. @PeterTaylor Perhaps you could use (and link to) [Charles Hannum's explanation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/DeCSS/Gallery/hannum-pal.html) of the algorithm and post this. (It would be fun to have it as a popularity contest for a program that *looks* like it's nothing DeCSS related, or a program that furthers the gallery's point about the text vs source code arbitrary distinction - but I don't know if popularity contests are popular any more!)

Answer (score 1):

### Write a compiler/interpreter for ...

Inspired by the lisp challenge here.
It is a series of puzzles.

I don't like to see a simple `eval` solution, so:

- interpreting the language is fine
- translating the language to a different language is fine.

I think this is specific for each language.

Only the syntax and the basic commands.
Also specific.

Winning criteria should not be code golf.
The goal should be that you can "learn" an other language by looking at the code.

Languages that might be good candidates:

- Lisp
- APL
- J
- Brainfuck (already [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck))
- Whitespace
- Forth

Comment: This only works for languages which are small and well defined. BF fits those criteria. Whitespace does too. The others may not. Lisp and Forth have so many dialects that you would have to specify exactly which dialect to support; Lisp, Forth, APL and J might have too many built-ins to fit in an answer: there are character limits.

Comment: You don't have to provide all the built-ins, but that is why it is here.

Comment: What defines the "basic commands"?

Comment: I don't know? Maybe that you can do the basic stuff with it like +,-,print,...

Comment: I suggest a programmer can implement the tiniest subset of those languages in order to be Turing-complete, as these are non-trivial subsets that can theoretically simulate the rest of the language...

Comment: Which human is learning the programming language by looking at the code?

Answer (score 1):

## Missile Command

I'm making this CW, because it needs *lots* of help. I've been toying with this idea for a while. Think "battleship" to get in the right mind-frame. But, instead of ships, what you lay down are tiles which represent a Befunge-style program. This program controls the behavior of guided missiles ejected from the *spawn* tile. The goal is to program a missile which will obliterate an opponent's program block, as well as guard its own control block.

Haven't nailed-down the board size. 20x20 seems a little cramped.

```
         1         2
12345678901234567890
____________________1  4x20 program block
____________________2
____________________3
_______@____________4
....................5  12x20 arena
....................6
....................7
....................8
....................9
....................01
....................1
....................2
....................3
....................4
....................5
....................6
___________@________7  4x20 program block
____________________8
____________________9
____________________02
```

### Tiles

`@` *spawn*

Program control.

I'm imagining these to change direction of the code for "boustrophedon" writing.

```
this,then\
 txen,siht
```

haven't thought it all though, yet.

`/`

`\`

Movement.

`F` *forward* move forward one square

`B` *back* move back one square

`L` *left* turn left 90°

`R` *right* turn right 90°

So the submissions would be 4x20 code blocks which compete in a king-of-the-hill style.

Comment: If this is deterministic, won't it be "Last person to submit their program wins"?

Comment: That is a danger, yes. I'm hoping ways around it can be found. There could be a random operator. And proximity detection, or something.

Answer (score 1):

### Find all of the Scrabble numbers:

A scrabble number is a number `n` whose scrabble representation can score `n` points. As an example consider `12`: its English spelling `twelve` has value `12` when it is placed on a stretch of six blank tiles. Since the highest ever reported 1 word scrabble score barely exceeds `2000` points, that will be the upperbound for this challenge.

Score and quantities for English:

```
2 blanks |  x1  |  x2  |  x3  |  x4  |  x6  |  x8  |  x9  |  x12 |
    1    |      |      |      | LSU  | NRT  | O    | AI   | E    |
    2    |      |      | G    | D    |      |      |      |      |
    3    |      | BCMP |      |      |      |      |      |      |
    4    |      | FHVWY|      |      |      |      |      |      |
    5    | K    |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
    8    | JX   |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
   10    | QZ   |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
```

Considerations for either bonus points to scoring or extra requirements:

- Respect the board, only using gaps between double/triple letter and double/triple word scores that occur on a standard scrabble board.
- Respect the tile count for each letter.
- There are non-English versions of scrabble, maybe it should be 'language-agnostic' (lol, but seriously is there a reason to accept only English submissions?).
- Should the 2 blanks be allowed?

Comment: What about tiles which were already on the board and so wouldn't score anything? As for language: one approach would be to make it take the names of the tiles (and perhaps the values and counts of the letters) as input; this would also prevent the problem from being effectively one of Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: I don't believe that tiles on the board already would pose an issue. If you assume that the board may be prepared with any subset of the tiles beforehand (some may be impossible, but checking that is out of scope) all that is relevant to the problem is which are placed to complete the word. All the tiles points are counted, even the earlier placed, but only the new 7 (or less) tiles may qualify for triple/double-word/letter scores. w.r.t. kolmogorov, If I wanted to make it programming challenge instead of codegolf (so that isn't an issue) then there needs to be a scoring system right?

Comment: Yes, if it isn't codegolf then it needs a scoring system. I'm not sure what you could use as an alternative scoring criterion, though: it's simple enough logic that pretty much any implementation would be IO-bound, so speed doesn't work; and big-O based tends to be less straightforward than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

## Sort all lines according to their corresponding Levenshtein Distance to the first line.

Shamelessly borrowed from: http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Levenshtein+Distance+Sort+FIXED

For a definition of the Levenshtein Distance, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_algorithm

Rules:

Takes input from stdin.
Must work for all possible input.
Get points for:

Smallest character count.
Using Languages that are difficult to golf in.
I think character count / the average values from here (http://golf.shinh.org/lranking.rb) might suffice?

Comment: There are a number of ambiguities in the problem description. What is the correct behaviour if the input is empty? In the general case, should the first line be included in the lines which are sorted and output? Should the sort be by ascending or descending edit distance? How should ties be broken?

Comment: As for handicapping: are you going to prohibit built-in or library-provided edit distance functions? If not then the averages you link are not especially relevant: PHP handily wins the [existing edit distance question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5174/194) by virtue of its built-in function.

Comment: (That existing question does also raise the possibility of yours being closed for not being sufficiently different).

Answer (score 1):

## Quine with syntax highlighting

---

I don't really have much of an idea how to properly pose a quine challenge, or what the common syntax highlighting rules are (or aren't) for various languages. So, I figured I'd just toss this concept up here for consideration and let the community flesh it out if they think it's a good idea.

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I'm pretty sure some languages don't even _have_ syntax to highlight

Comment: @JanDvorak Perhaps this would not quite be an "all languages" challenge, then - only languages which naturally lend themselves to syntax highlighting would be eligible.

Comment: You also can't use a language that cannot render any decent GUI. Also, specifying the amount of syntax highlighting the program needs to generate will be hell.

Comment: I don't think this question is feasible, due to the output restrictions and due to the difficulty in defining the minimum required syntax highlighting.

Comment: I like this idea. I think you could specify an adequate level of highlighting with just keywords, strings or characters and numeric literals each having their own color.

Comment: How would the syntax highlighting apply to the output?

Answer (score 1):

## McDonald's Drive-Thru

> **Changes from original:**
>
> - Provided some clarification of requirements with regards to impossible ordering quantities.
> - Added specification to include total cost of order.
> - Added specification to prefer lowest cost in case of a tie for number of packages.
>
> **TODO:**
>
> - Verify package sizes and pricing to be used for this challenge.
> - Add pricing to output samples.
> - Edit or remove "not have any limitations" rule. As currently written, it may force otherwise unnecessary bloating of code in some languages. (e.g.: PowerShell can handle numbers as uint64 to work with extremely large quantities, but it defaults to int32.)

We want to write a program to help McDonald's Drive-Thru employees assist their customers in ordering Chicken McNuggets. Chicken McNuggets only come in packs of 4, 6, 9, or 20. However, customers may not always be considering this when they pull up to the speaker.

For example, a customer might want to order 50 McNuggets but they really don't care what sort of packaging they come in - they just want to make sure they get 50 McNuggets one way or another. We want to help the customers get the best value out of their order - that is, to compose an order large enough to accommodate their needs in as few packages as possible with little to no excess.

Users will provide a request for *n* Chicken McNuggets. Your program's task is to provide the user with the sizes and numbers of McNugget packages needed to fulfill the order exactly. If the exact order cannot be fulfilled, the system must output an order which would meet the customer's needs with as little excess as possible. The system must also provide the total cost of the order.

### Rules

- For values of *n* which can be ordered exactly, output how many of each pack must be ordered to achieve the requested quantity.
- For impossible orders (1,2,3,5,7,11), print "[requested quantity] is impossible. Have [nearest valid quantity >*n*]:" followed by the normal output for the nearest possible quantity >*n*.
- Impossible orders cannot be hard-coded. The program must be able to determine whether fulfilling an order exactly is possible without being explicitly told that 1,2,3,5,7, and 11 are impossible.
- Output must exclude any package sizes which do not need to be ordered.
- Output must be in descending order of package size.
- Output must include the sum total cost of all the packages. (Tax not included.)
- Further layout and formatting of the output is up to you, so long as it is unambiguous.
- Program must not have any limitations beyond those inherent to the system or programming language.
- If there are multiple ways to assemble the order in the least number of packages, output the method which has the lowest total price.

**Examples:**

Input: `8`
Output:

```
2x4
```

Input: `43`
Output:

```
1x20 1x9 1x6 2x4
```

Input: `11`
Output:

```
11 is impossible. Have 12: 2x6
```

[Relevant Numberphile Link](http://numberphile.com/videos/43_nuggets.html)

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

My main concern is that this problem may be too similar to this thread:

[Work out change](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/647/work-out-change)

Otherwise, are there any changes that should be made to this?

Comment: My recommendation is to minimize the total cost of the order, rather than the number of packages.  Based on these prices: http://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/mcdonalds-prices/,  the costs are $2.99, $3.89, $4.29, and $5.00.  This website lists the "9 piece" as "10 piece",  I think that might be an error.

Comment: Why the restriction #3?

Comment: I agree that it's too similar to the existing question. In addition, "nearest valid quantity" isn't unique, and you don't give any hint as to how to break ties.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Tiebreaker is specified as ">n", where "n" is the quantity requested by the user - that is, we want to give the user an option that will have at least as many nuggets as they want to order.

Comment: @JanDvorak Essentially, to up the difficulty a notch. I figure it's a little trickier to catch the invalid quantities in the process of figuring out the answer if you can't write a simple if statement to match against the known quantities.

Comment: @PhiNotPi Not sure if that's an error on the site, or a regional difference. The information I posted was based on the linked Numberphile video, which was made in the U.K.. It's also possible they may have changed the menu since then. Presuming that larger packages hold better value in terms of cost-per-nugget than smaller ones, the problem as stated should work itself out to the same goal as you've suggested. However, it might help to differentiate the challenge from the suggested duplicate if we add the total price into the expected output.

Comment: My question is: how are you going to measure that? How large part of this knowledge are we disallowed from encoding? Can we memorize all but one? Can we special-case 1,2,3? Or, is it that anything goes as long as it either can be generalised to other Frobenius problems, or is inclusive, not exclusive?

Comment: @JanDvorak The program should be able to work out for itself whether or not a given quantity is invalid - that's all there is to it. By its nature, I suppose that means solutions would be able to also handle other Frobenius problems. In fact, I was actually considering a separate "return the largest impossible quantity" problem, where users input several integers and the program outputs the largest quantity that cannot be achieved by adding multiples of those integers.

Comment: Provided some updates to address comments.

Comment: @Iszi Minimizing cost should serve as a tiebreaker for when there are multiple solutions with the minimum packaging.  For example, look at N=36. The solution `{0*4,0*6,4*9,0*20}` works, but `{1*4,2*6,0*9,1*20}` is cheaper.  (I used the costs `{{4,2.99},{6,3.89},{9,4.29},{20,5.00}}`)

Comment: @PhiNotPi Ah, I think I misunderstood when Peter said there wasn't a specifier for the tiebreaker. For some reason, I was thinking it was not possible for there to be a tie of that sort. Adding the price aspect definitely helps sort that out, then. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, it was my misreading. I failed to see the ">n".

Answer (score 1):

## .... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..

Another Hello World challenge, this time with Morse code!

Taking no input, your program must output `HELLO WORLD` in audible Morse code, printing each letter as it is played. For the purpose of this challenge, the following Morse code guidelines will be followed:

**Duration of sounds:**

- Dits are one time-unit long.
- Dahs are three time-units long.
- The gap between elements within the same character is equal to one dit.
- The gap between characters within the same word is equal to one dah.
- The gap between words is seven time units long.
- The length of "one time unit" is up to the programmer, so long as it is consistent throughout the message.

**Letters:**

- H: `....`
- E: `.`
- L: `.-..`
- O: `---`
- W: `.--`
- R: `.-.`
- D: `-..`

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

I'm a little iffy on that last bullet regarding duration. Should I set a hard standard, or a minimum? If so, what to?

Comment: Set a hard minimum for timing.  Otherwise, a golfed solution might have 1 unit = 1 millisecond.

Comment: Tasks which take input are normally more interesting.

Comment: I guess that dahs  need to be a continuous tone, not just two dits without a gap?

Comment: @JanDvorak Correct.

Comment: If you don't plan to post this, I would like to modify it and post it. (If you don't reply to this message within two weeks, by community standards, I am allowed to adopt the challenge.)

Comment: @MDXF What do you suggest for modifications?

Answer (score 1):

## Find Maximum number of 4+ letter words from Scabble Tiles

The challenge is to find the most words with 4 or more letters you can make with one set of scrabble tiles.

The tile distribution is as follows:

```
2 Blank Tiles
A 9  N 6    +====+===========+
B 2  O 8    | 01 | K J X Q Z |
C 2  P 2    | 02 | B C M P F |
D 4  Q 1    | 02 | H V W Y * |
E 12 R 6    | 03 | G         |
F 2  S 4    | 04 | L S U D   |
G 3  T 6    | 06 | N R T     |
H 2  U 4    | 08 | O         |
I 9  V 2    | 09 | A I       |
J 1  W 2    | 12 | E         |
K 1  X 1    +====+===========+
L 4  Y 2
M 2  Z 1
```

Valid words are any words that are 4+ that are available in [this file](http://pywordgame.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/wordgame/wordgame/model/ospd4.txt), the official scrabble dictionary.

Tiles cannot be used twice. This means you can only have 1 word with a K, J, X, Q, and/or Z unless you use a blank tile to represent one of these letters.

I'm not sure how I'd do scoring on this. I want shorter code to score better, but I don't want a short piece of code that finds a lot less words to score better than a longer piece that finds many more words.

Comment: Meh. I don't like dependency on external files; are we allowed to load it, or even embed it into the source code?

Comment: as for finding more vs. shorter code, you could demand all words be found

Comment: @JanDvorak Any way to use it. It's a text version of the official scrabble dictionary, it seemed to be the most fitting word list for the task. "All words being found" might be hard, considering there are probably many combinations of words that would deplete all the tiles. It's a maximum of 25 words, (25 words, 4 letters each, 100 tiles), but I don't know if it's possible to use all tiles with just 4 letter words. After so many words, you might not have enough tiles to make an actual word, which means you'd either have to go back or accept that you're not using all the tiles.

Comment: As currently described, this is a no-input task, which means that the answer can be precomputed and then the program only needs to decompress it. Consider rewriting it to take input (either of the word list or of the tiles available).

Comment: I suggest taking a list of tiles as input, loading the list of words from a predefined file and requiring all combinations / best combination to be found. Of course, if the input is the full list of tiles, the computation is going to take ages. I might allow preprocessing the word list outside the program itself (up to a certain point; a linearithmic growth?)

Comment: I suggest modifying this so that input is a list of tiles, limited to a full rack or less (therefore 4-7 tiles, since our minimum word length is 4). Input should be assumed to be valid based on the standard set of tiles (e.g.: it wont' have something like 3 J's or 4 G's). This would have some practical use for a player in a scrabble game to figure out their next move (though it does not take into account tiles available to them which are already on the board).

Comment: Alternative mode: Input is a list of tiles, maximum 96 (so that at least 4 are remaining in the set). Output only includes words (minimum 4 letters) which can be created *without* those tiles. This would be interesting as it provides words that may yet be created (though, again, not taking into account usable tiles on the board) at a given point in the game.

Comment: Output needs to be decided as either a list of all possible words, or only the highest-scoring word(s). Another enhancement may be to require that the list be sorted descending in order of score (if output is all words), then ascending alphabetically. There's no reason to take each program's output into account for scoring. Since everyone is expected to use the same dictionary, all programs' outputs should be identical (except perhaps in sorting, if that's left out of the spec). So, this should be Code Golf.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, as currently written, the task could just be to filter the given dictionary down to words which have 4 or more letters. By its very nature, the Scrabble dictionary should already exclude any words that cannot be made with a Scrabble set.

Comment: @Iszi it's not "what are all the words you can make", it's "what are all the words you can make, where every letter used depletes a tile". There's a max of 25 words if you can use all 100 tiles.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem, then. I thought it was "all the words possible using a set of tiles" not "all the words possible, using *only one* set of tiles". Still, my point about code golf remains. There is an absolute maximum to the number of words (each with 4 or more letters) you can make with a single Scrabble set, and a finite number of permutations which can be used to hit that maximum. Every program written with this goal should end up with the same (or nominally similar) output.

Answer (score 1):

### Code Golf: counting all colors in an image

The goal of this Code Golf is to create a program that counts all colors in an image.

#### The input

The input will be a path to the image file.

#### The output

The output should be a number that indicates how much different colors your program found in the image.

#### The scoring

It's also important that your program supports much image formats, so I'll calculate the score based on this formula:

```
(character_count * 3) / (number_of_supported_image_formats * 2)
```

#### Some other rules

- The lowest score wins
- You're not allowed to execute an external program
- No Internet access
- A color doesn't just count if it's present in the palette, there really should be pixels of that color in the image.
- You should also count pixels with 0% opacity.
- `#FFFFFF` with 100% opacity is **not** the same color as `#FFFFFF` with 50% (of course, this is the same for all other colors).
- In vector image formats, if there's a red square (for example) with 50% opacity that overlaps a blue square, then this should count as two colors: red and blue.
- In vector image formats, in case of a gradient, the number of colors depend on which colors are used in the gradient. For example, if there is a red/yellow gradient, then you should count this as two colors: red and yellow.
- A paletted image format is *another* image format than the non-paletted variant.
- SVG 1.0 is *another* image format than SVG 1.1 (also count for other image formats).

Comment: What counts as a colour? Does a colour count as present if it's in the palette, even if there aren't any pixels of that colour? What about if it's present, but at 0% opacity? On the subject of opacity, are #ffffff at 100% opacity and #ffffff at 50% opacity the same colour? What about vector image formats: does a red square at 50% opacity partially overlapping a blue square count as two colours (red and blue) or three (red, magenta in the overlap, and blue)? What about gradients: does the number of colours depend on the size of the gradient-coloured object?

Comment: Also, what counts as an image format? If a program supports paletted PNG but not non-paletted PNG, does that count as 0 formats, 0.5 formats, or 1 format? If a program supports SVG 1.0 and SVG 1.1 does that count as 1 format or 2 formats? Etc.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks for your comments! I updated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid the core of this challenge is to be as bold as possible when counting the amount of file formats my language's standard library can handle.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Of course, you should also look whether it's really worth to handle another image format, after you made sure to handle some other. If your score doesn't get lower, then it's not really worth.

Answer (score 1):

Since [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15954/output-the-correct-move-as-per-the-xkcd-tic-tac-toe-cheetsheet) is closed, I figured I'd post it here so further issues can be hammered out in Meta instead of the main site.

> **Known Issues:**
>
> - Some rules seem a bit unclear to some users.
> - Clarification may be needed on what is needed to qualify for the "win percentage" bonus.
> - Win percentage bonus may not be enough to be a real incentive. (This may just depend on the language or implementation.)
> - Perhaps the win percentage bonus should be eliminated entirely, or maybe it should just be made a mandatory part of the spec.
> - It's been suggested to use a simple 1-9 numbering system for the board positions, instead of any sort of X,Y coordinates.
> - May want to allow some flexibility on the input format. (i.e.: Input must still specify the sequence of moves thus far, using whatever addressing scheme is specified in the spec, but leave the delimiters - or lack thereof - up to the developer.)
> - Exactly what is expected of the program, such as how it can figure out whose turn it is or what the output should be, seems to need some clarification.
> - Some test cases should probably be added.
> - Clarification may be needed on the matter of what parts of the game we can assume have followed the guide already.
> - Some flaws exist in the chart. (Two already mentioned in comments on the original post.) These should be identified and addressed so that proper expectations for those conditions are clearly set.
> - Original post said we would not have to account for null input (i.e.: X asking what their first move should be) but this might be a good enhancement to add.

I personally think this is a great challenge. So far, I've had a very hard time finding a lot of room for optimization and got up to probably 400 characters in PowerShell before I gave up (not even half-way through the chart yet) due to some of the above issues. I'd really like to see what some more serious golfers could do with this, once the spec is properly hammered out.

---

### Overview

[This](http://xkcd.com/832_large/) is the XKCD tic-tac-toe cheetsheet:

[image]

It's rather big, I know. But it's also your most valuable resource in your challenge.

### The challenge

Create a program (in your language of choice) that uses the Optimal Move Cheatsheet (henceforth OMC) to output the optimal move when given a sequence of moves.

### The input

Your program will be fed a series of moves in the following fashion:

```
A3 A2 B2 C2 ...
```

Where the first combination is always X, the second O, and so on. The letter is the Y coordinate (`A-C`, A at the top) and the number is the X coordinate (`1-3`, 1 at the left).

You may assume that the given combination is following the OMC's suggestion for each move at least for the player asking for a recommendation. You can also assume that the input will never be null (at least one move has been made). You must:

1. Figure out whether the next move is for X or O (you don't need to output this)
2. Use the OMC to decide the next move
3. Print the next move in the standard format `A3`

### Optional:

You may also include the player's chance of winning (as a percentage) for 50 character discount on your score.

Comment: I think a 1-9 system would be easier than any `XY` system, but not by too much. The biggest issue I think is that if you go by the chart (rather than formulating your own algorithm that plays the same way) you have a ton of data to enter (there are several hundred squares in the two charts). Perhaps limit the input to only sequences starting `A1 B2` (or `1 5` if you use telephone keypad numbering)? That's the center square in the `X` chart and the top left square in the `O` chart.

Comment: @Blckknght Limiting the scope of the challenge makes it less interesting. Part of the challenge (if not the entire challenge) here is to find ways to shortcut the flow while still putting out accurate results. As for the 1-9 system, the simplification may be relatively trivial but it does help clear out some otherwise unneeded bloat since everyone will probably build in some conversion to a 1-9 system anyway to shorten the code. It also enables some other shortcuts where the same move suggestion applies to multiple situations which are mathematically related.

Comment: My point is that the chart data so dominates the code size that winning answers will pretty much have to ignore the data in the chart and use an AI. So the challenge becomes "write a Tic-Tac-Toe AI that plays exactly like this chart", which seems less interesting to me than "use (part of) this chart to make an AI with trivial code". I already have working code for the problem and bonus in about 200 non-golfed characters of Python, but it will require many 1000s of characters of data, even if I exploit some symmetries. Even if I was willing to type all that data, an AI will beat it, I'm sure.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm pretty sure even a fairly straightforward implementation of the chart can be fit within about 5,000 characters - especially in a proper golfing language. IRRC, I'd finished the X portion of the chart in about 400 characters with PowerShell before I gave up on my first go at it. Even then, there was still plenty of room for optimization, and that's in a language which is *far* from optimal for golfing. Certainly, it's nice when you can bang out a quick answer in 15 minutes. But not every challenge has to fit in 500 characters or less.

Answer (score 1):

### Implement addition using only division (code golf)

Thought you could [implement division using only addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/implement-division-using-only-addition)? Well try it the other way around!

Your job is to make a function or equivalent program that accepts 2 numbers and adds them using only division.

### Rules

- No importing libraries
- You can't use anything dealing with mathematics except `/` and `/=`, (and their equivalents)
- No bitwise operations
- No string operations except input, output, return, and string concatenation

Comment: Interesting.  You might have to close some loopholes, though, as some people will just create a giant lookup table. Also, some people could use string operations use perform addition. Is it going to be code golf?

Comment: @PhiNotPi I think so, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does "no string operations" refer to I/O as well? It's hard to do I/O without string operations of any kind

Comment: @JanDvorak I want to allow I/O - how do I rephrase the question as to allow I/O without allowing math by executing strings?

Comment: "division using only division" looks like an error...

Comment: Is this a code golf, code challenge or a popularity contest?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks :) And @ ProgramFOX, it's code golf.

Comment: @Timtech Not the number of divisions required?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn What are you talking about?

Comment: Tried to calculate `0+0` - the only thing I accomplished was a *division by zero* ;-)

Comment: How do you prevent solutions like `Array(a).concat(Array(b)).concat([0,0]).length`?

Comment: Is eliminating string concatenation too restrictive? Maybe only allow the built in conversions from strings to numeric types.

Comment: @Tim I guess so, maybe just disallow eval/expr.

Comment: and would mod be allowed?

Comment: @Tim As it currently stands, no. Do you think I should add it?

Comment: I am not sure how much it helps, was only curious. I still haven't figured out an obvious way to solve it without "cheating". Or how to change the wording so that unwanted solutions are not allowed.

Comment: @Tim I don't either :)

Answer (score 1):

## Resurrect Adobe SubScript.

In an obscure conference procedings volume of forgotton lore, there's a quaint little paper which describes an early effort to implement a published subset of Adobe Postscript. There a line in the bibliography! :) [But it cannot be found](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/C9fTi03DvWo/discussion.) Nobody's ever heard of it. :(

> Adobe Systems, "SubScript Specification", 1984.

But there's obvious utility in such a thing. So this is a hypothetical *Micro-Manual* Postscript, and its name shall be ASS[*]. :)

ASS is a dynamically-typed stack-based programming language with powerful graphics primitives. It has support for floating-point arithmetic, arrays and dictionaries.

The scanner reads white-space delimited tokens and attempts to interpret the token as a decimal floating-point number with optional sign (+/-). The program may (but is not required to) support exponential notation. Failing to recognize a valid number, the token becomes a name object, an atomic symbol type which is identified by the name (an "interned" string).

## Types

As suggested by the scanner behavior and the operator list , there are the following object types:

- **floating-point** numbers (coerced to integer where appropriate)
- **names** (usually an index into a string table, for easy comparisons)
- **arrays** (an indexable sequence of objects)
- **dictionaries** (a key-value map of objects)
- **operators** (a pointer to a built-in function)

## Operators

Operators are the basic actions predefined in the dynamic name space.

### Stack Manipulation

- *any*    **pop**     *-*
  *pop an object from the operand stack*
- *any<sub>1</sub>*  *any<sub>2</sub>*     **exch**     *any<sub>2</sub>*  *any<sub>1</sub>*
  *exchange top two elements*
- *any<sub>N</sub>*  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>0</sub>*  *N*     **index**     *any<sub>N</sub>*  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>0</sub>*  *any<sub>N</sub>*
  *retrieve object from stack by position*

where *N* is treated as an integer.

### Arrays.

- *N*     **array**     *array*
  *create a new array of length N*
- *any<sub>0</sub>*  *any<sub>1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  *array*     **astore**     *array*
  *fill array with objects from stack*
- *array*     **aload**     *any<sub>0</sub>*  *any<sub>1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  *array*
  *spill contents of array onto stack*
- **[**     *any<sub>0</sub>*  *any<sub>1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*     **]**     *array*
  *construct an array*
- *array*  *index*  *any*     **put**     *-*
  *put a value into array*
- *array*  *index*     **get**     *any*
  *retrieve value from array*

where *index* is treated as an integer.

The typical way to implement the array syntax is using an auxiliary type, the marktype object, and an operator **counttomark**. This is an implementation detail and is not strictly required but may be found to be convenient.

- *-*     **[**     *mark*
  *produce marktype object as a sentinel on the stack*
- *mark*  *any<sub>N</sub>*  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>1</sub>*     **counttomark**     *mark*  *any<sub>N</sub>*  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>1</sub>*  *N*
  *count objects up to mark*

Then the **]** operator may be implemented in terms of the other array operators.

- *mark*  *any<sub>N</sub>*  *any<sub>N-1</sub>*  ...  *any<sub>1</sub>*     **]**     *array*
  *{ counttomark array astore exch pop }*

### Dictionaries.

- *N*     **dict**     *dict*
  *create a new dictionary, an associative container with room for N name-value pairs*
- *dict*     **begin**     *-*
  *push dictionary on dictionary stack, making names part of the dynamic name space*
- *-*     **currentdict**     *dict*
  *push copy of topmost dictionary on dictionary stack to the operand stack*
- *-*     **end**     *-*
  *pop and discard the topmost dictionary on the dictionary stack*
- *name*  *any*     *def*     *-*
  *associate name with any value in topmost dictionary*
- *name*     **load**     *any*
  *lookup name in each dictionary in the dictionary stack from the top-down, returning the first match, or error if not found*

### Matrices and transformations.

A matrix is a 6-number array `[a b c d e f]` which represent a left-multiplying affine transformation matrix with the constant right-most column omitted.

```
 a b 0
 c d 0  =>  [a b c d e f]
 e f 1
```

- *-*     **matrix**     *matrix*
  *returns a new identity matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]*
- *matrix*     **setmatrix**     *-*
  *make matrix the current transform in the graphics state*
- *-*     **currentmatrix**     *matrix*
  *return current transform from the graphics state*
- *x*  *y*     **transform**     *x′*  *y′*
  *transform (x,y) pair by current transformation matrix*

Transforming a point involves multiplying the homogeneous vector through the transformation matrix:

```
          [a b 0]
[x y 1] * [c d 0] => [x' y' 1]
          [e f 1]
```

or, equivalently

```
x' = a*x + c*y + e
y' = b*x + d*y + f
```

### Path description.

- *-*     **newpath**     *-*
- *x*  *y*     **moveto**     *-*
- *x*  *y*     **lineto**     *-*
- *-*     **closepath**    *-*

### Clipping.

- *-*     **clip**     *-*
- *-*     **clippath**     *-*

### Painting.

- *-*     **erasepage**     *-*
- *-*     **fill**     *-*
- *-*     **showpage**     *-*

The **fill** operator is where the magic happens. This operator is responsible for performing all of the graphics algorithms in sequence:

- Shape Mapping
  *Tranform the coordinates of the path from user space to device space using the current transformation matrix.*
- Shape Clipping
  *Clip the portions of the path that lie outside the clipping path.*
- Filling
  *Perform a scan-line rasterization of the (may assumed closed-) polygon described by the path into the output frame buffer.

And **showpage** copies the contents of the framebuffer to the actual output mechanism (window or file as described above).

... need to fill this out a little more. Math, graphics state, errors. Describing stroked lines is too much, I think. I'm not sure if it needs the **forall** operators for iterating through arrays and dicts. I'd like to avoid any need for overloading different types under the same operator name, and calling back to user code from an operator.

Output may be to a window, or to a file in a simple format, like pgm or even a text-file of hashes and spaces for rough bitmaps. No half-toning. Only bi-level filling of convex polygons will be required. But a program may handle more colors if desired.

This is *CW* in case anybody wants to help me type-in the basic operators.

## Questions

Does it need anything more? Should something be removed as unnecessary? Does anyone *have the spec*??

Perusing my ps implementations of the graphics portions linked in the comments, I've noticed the following needed operators:

```
length
sub
roll
add
eq
array copy
mul
div
ne
```

I think it needs loops, too. It's possible to do with just recursion, of course, but loops are nice. And `length`, I think, needs to be polymorphic, operating on *array* or *dict* to retrieve the size for making copies and calculating indices. Add `sin` and `cos`, too.

---

And this would be a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

[*] The moniker "ASS" is not intended as a disparagement of Adobe Systems nor any of their stupendous intellectual property. Rather it is merely intended to express frustration at the encountered difficulty in locating this document.

Comment: So this is intended to be a subset of PostScript: are you going to point people at a PS spec for the nitty-gritty details about things like the precise implementation of path filling? Also, if the idea is to be minimalistic, why have both `mark` and `[`?

Comment: I'm hoping I can concisely specify everything so it's self-contained and not need to refer to a PS spec. ... Good point about `mark`. I suppose I can require `[` and `]` and suggest `mark` ... `counttomark` as a possible way to implement it.

Comment: oh. I see what you mean now. removed `mark` as a separate entity. It isn't needed.

Comment: My idea is to follow the most basic part of the original Warnock paper which is the basis of the Adobe Image Model. I've got some excerpts [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/wrkPdGdw8cE/discussion).

Comment: I don't see any way to create a non-identity matrix.

Comment: You can construct any matrix using the array notation. There should also be user space transforms: rotate, scale and translate. They're usually part of the graphics state, so I didn't put them under matrices.

Comment: This spec from the 80s would be *gold* for implementing postscript. Offering a glimpse at the intermediate stage between the Warnock/Wyatt paper (which describes the image model in the syntax of the Xerox Mesa language) and the PLRM 1ed. Warnock/Wyatt has been described as "smuggling" the ideas out of Xerox. ... Ugh. I forgot to add some control structures.

Comment: I've got implementations of [paths](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/data/path.ps), [matrices](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/data/matrix.ps), [clipping](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/data/clip.ps), and [filling](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/data/ppmimage.ps) in postscript. Perhaps I should wrap these up and just require the data structures and scanning to load and use them.

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Comment: Thanks! ... Done.

Answer (score 1):

### Code-Golf: Write a number as an expression that's as short as possible

The goal of this code-golf is to create a program that takes a number as input (using STDIN, command line arguments, or prompting for input), and outputs that number, but written as an expression **that's as short as possible**. So, `10000` should become `10^4`. If there is no way to write an expression that's shorter than the number, then output just the number.

#### Other rules

1. No network access.
2. You're not allowed to execute an external program.
3. Only use the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `^` (that's raising power, not XOR).
4. Order of operations must be taken in account. Use parentheses if necessary.
5. This is a code golf, so the code with the smallest amount of characters wins.
6. The input will always be smaller than `2^32`.

#### Test cases

```
500000000   -->    5*10^8     or    10^9/2
999999      -->    10^6-1
10          -->    10
4294967295  -->    2^32-1
16384       -->    2^14
```

Comment: basically the same approach as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12063/four-fours-puzzle, except with one extra loop.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Recognize spoken numbers of .wav file

The goal of this code golf is to create a program or function that recognizes (and outputs) the spoken numbers of a Waveform Audio File (.wav).
The rules are:

1. No network access and you are not allowed to run external programs.
2. The input will be the file path to the WAV file, and the spoken text will only be one of these digits: `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` or `five`.
3. The output must be the recognized spoken number of the WAV file.
4. You are not allowed to use third-party libraries.
5. This is a code golf, so the code with the smallest character count wins.

Comment: What do you mean by *convert to text*? Encode? Recognise spoken text?

Comment: @Howard: Recognize spoken text. I updated my question.

Comment: That makes it a very subjective challenge. It is quite debatable if a wav file contains recognisable text or not. I can't think of a safe way to put restrictions on the input without making it to a fixed-input kind of puzzle.

Comment: @Howard: You mean, for example, ensuring that the input will only be spoken text without background music?

Comment: This needs some explicit restrictions on input. I assume that you're assuming that the text will be English, but even then there is a lot of accent variety. Most speech-to-text programs which U.S. companies release can't handle many (if any) British accents in their first version or two. I think that the only way this can be reasonably objective is either to invert a TTS program (in which case it's boring - no errors to account for) or to specify a training text and a test text, where it gets to hear the training text read n times and then tries to interpret the test text.

Comment: Maybe it is possible if you restrict the challenge to recognise the spoken digits one, two, three and four. Although still difficult to define *clearly spoken* there may be small enough variation in the input.

Comment: Maybe you can make a youtube video or something similar that contains all the sound that needs to be recognized; the programs just need to cater to those sounds.

Comment: @Howard: That's a good suggestion. I updated my question.

Comment: What's a "third-party library"? Can C# programs use MS libraries, Obj-C programs use Apple libraries, etc?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Yes, they can.

Comment: Golfing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx would make for a rather short and boring answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, ProgramFOX: It would make sense to forbid any libraries or programs designed for speech recognition, whether third-party or not. You might want to take a look at my earlier [speech synthesis challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12204/speak-digits-from-0-to-9-aloud) for some ideas on how to word such challenges (and in the comments for some issues I *should've* thought of in advance).

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Print Lorem ipsum

The goal of this code golf is to write a program that prints **EXACTLY** this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The rules:

1. No external resources
2. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is there any reason to expect the answers to be fundamentally different to those to existing [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] questions?

Comment: Won't the winner just post something like `cout<<"/*text here*/";`?  This will probably be pretty boring, as the text needs to be hardcoded in.

Comment: @user2509848: No, I'd expect the winner to be something that packs the text in base 29 or 32 into a raw byte string and decodes it in GolfScript or some similar language. Or possibly some PHP code that starts with `<?=gzinflate(`.

Comment: OK, but you will need to specify that in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's my first proposal. It just occurred to me that it might be a bit difficult testing submissions without a functioning server, but maybe we can manage without? What do you people think?

---

The web hosting company I use has a jobs page that looks a bit like this:

[image: Screenshot of web page]

If you want to work for them, you have to calculate the correct answer and submit it through this form. But you only have a few seconds in which to do this, so you need a script to do it for you. If you submit the correct answer in time, you're then given a hash code and an email address, and are asked to email your source code to this address, using the hash code as the subject line:

[image: Screenshot of next page after a successful submission]

Using any language you like, write a script to download and submit this application form with the correct answer and hidden `id` field, and then email your source code with the hash code provided as the subject line. You can assume that the HTML source of the two pages is as follows:

## 1. http://jobs.example.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Job Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Evaluate 943 + 376 - 394 * 573 * 983 , and submit the answer with the following form.</p>
<form method="POST" action="apply.pl">
<input type="text" name="answer" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## 2. http://jobs.example.com/apply.pl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Job Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Well done, that was the correct answer. Now email your source
code to jobs@example.com with the following text in the Subject
header:</p>
<p><code>1a79a4d60de6718e8e5b326e338ae533</code></p>
<p>But hurry, you only have five seconds!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The only variable parts of these pages are:

1. The sum (up to 6 numbers separated by any combination of `+`, `-` and `*` with spaces on both sides)
2. The hidden `id` field that must be submitted with the form.
3. The hash code on the second page

You may assume that the sum can be calculated without overflow using 32-bit integer arithmetic.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: What's the difficulty with having a functioning server?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It won't be possible to actually test anyone's script without a server that can process these applications. This probably isn't a problem for sensible languages, but if someone submitted an answer written in Golfscript or Whitespace then I'd have no idea if it would actually work or not.

Comment: It won't be possible to test them anyway if you send the e-mail to `jobs@example.com`. I note that you haven't specified that you're after a program: I would specify that answers should be a full program which takes HTTP URL and e-mail address as command-line arguments or as separate lines on stdin; then each person can test with an e-mail address they control. If you're willing to change the URLs a bit then I can host a couple of PHP pages somewhere under cheddarmonk.org.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, of course! It didn't occur to me that the email address could be separated out as input data. We'd have to change the background story a bit though. Emailing a job application to yourself seems a bit daft.

Comment: I don't see why. If you're allowing people advance knowledge of the full HTML structure, you can assume that they have advance knowledge of the target e-mail, and then it's just a case of promoting testable code.

Answer (score 1):

## How many pizzas do I need

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program that figures out the minimum number of pizzas I need to order and the amount of left overs I will have.

#### Requirements

- Each pizza is 8 slices
- Each person gets one choice of pizza topping, represented by a letter `A-Z`
- Input in the format `PVBC 2`. Where each letter represents the choice of 1 person (e.g. `P`=Plain, `V`=Vegie, etc...), and the number is the amount of slices each person is allowed to eat. Letters can be in any order and do not need to be grouped.
- If I don't need a full pizza I must be able to do half one topping and half another topping, the output for a half and half pizza will be denoted by `X/Y` where `X` and `Y` are different toppings
- If I need multiple of a certain type of pizza they must be shown on one line (e.g. `2 x V Pizza`). If there are different combinations the both result in the same, least, amount of pizzas, either output works
- Output must match the format below of one type of pizza per line and a comma separated list of left overs. The output must show the minimum amount of pizzas and leftover possible.

#### Extra Credit

- **-20** - Take a 3rd argument that allows you to input the number of slices in a pizza, assume it will be an even number such that you can split it in half

Sample Input/Output

```
PCPVCB 3              (6 slices P, 3 slices V,  6 slices C, 3 slices B)
1 x P Pizza
1 x V/B Pizza
1 x C Pizza
2 slices P, 2 slices C, 1 slice V, 1 slice B left over

VBBCBBB 2             (10 slices B, 2 slices C, 2 slices V)
1 x C/V Pizza
2 x B Pizza
6 slices B, 2 slices C, 2 slices V left over
```

The 2nd example has many other combinations that could result in only 3 pizzas, this is just an example of what an output might be.

The shortest code wins.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I may have seen a similar challenge before.  If not, it seems good to me.

Comment: The use of the word "preferences" is confusing to me, because it suggests some kind of optimisation problem where people might get their second preference and you have to optimise for overall satisfaction. In addition, I don't find either the input or the output specification sufficiently clear. For the input, is there any guarantee that the letters are grouped (i.e. that `PVP 1` will never be given as input)? And are the 4 letters given the only ones which may be used, or could there potentially be 26 different preferences? How much flexibility is there in the output?

Comment: @Danny, the one problem with this question is that because of my voracious appetite, there would be *no* left over pizza... ;)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I made edits to hopefully address all of the parts you saw that were possibly confusing. Can you look at the question again and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Danny You might want to add that you want the minimum amount of ordered pizzas/left overs - otherwise there exists a trivial solution where each person gets his own pizza (provided slices<=8).

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.)

Answer (score 1):

**The Poet's Quine:**

Write a quine with 1 or more rhyme scheme from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme when read. The non-alphanumeric symbols aren't used for rhyming in this scheme (apart from the basic arithmetic signs like plus, minus, times and divided by), neither are comments. Words may be pronounced in any dialect, but it needs to be consistent within the same stanza (no having the first word be pronounced in a Scottish way and the second in a Welsh way).

Contest type would be popularity contest.

Thoughts on this proposal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last two points. Examples?

Comment: "words are pronounced without a heavy accent or dialect" seems to me to be incompatible with "worked and borked rhyme".

Comment: That was more intended to be an example of a rhyme in general, rather than a "no heavy accent" example. I'm not a native speaker, so my pronunciation might not be totally accurate. I'll drop that rule (also could make for more interesting interpretations).

Comment: It seems the scoring scheme actively encourages *bad* poetry. Maintaining a consistent rhyme scheme throughout is more difficult and better poetically, yet you penalize adjacent repetition of a scheme and give bonuses to unique schemes. Using syllables instead of feet is odd, too. A line of 12 syllables and a line of 8 can work perfectly together if one is anapests and the other iambs. I realize this is a programming site, but if you're going to call it "The Poet's Quine", let's have some real poetry!!

Comment: I'm not really someone who knows a lot about poetry, but those suggestions seem good. I didn't want to make it too complicated though. you say yourself that this site is for programmers, and I doubt there are many programmers out there that know the different di-, tri- and tetrasyllable feet. maybe having a properly feeted poem can be a bonus objective?

Comment: The biggest challenge will be finding a proper scoring system which makes sense both poetically and programmatically. It's definitely possible, but it won't be easy. Poetry is such a wide art and relies just as much on format as on content. And I don't want to force a specific kind of meter on the participants, because that's part of the challenge.

Comment: We could also make it a popularity contest, since poetry is not about the format and content, but about evoking emotions and feelings. A popularity contest might be suited more for such a puzzle.

Comment: Yeah, I think popularity contest solves a lot of the issues here. Of course, it also creates issues of its own, like the inexplicable number of "To be or not to be" entries on the aphorism challenge. But...lesser of two evils.  :)

Comment: What issues are you thinking about? maybe some extra rules can make this work.

Answer (score 1):

## The shortest C program which generates the most instructions

Write a very short C program (length being defined by character count) which generates the most instructions when compiled. Of course, indicate your compiler, the version, and your operating system, and say what your program does. Linked libraries do not count!

#### Score

- Base score: **1/(characters) * (instructions)**
- Bonus: if it computes something "useful," **+20%**

---

I'm fascinated by C challenges and compiler oddities, but I'm not sure about this question because of the variance you'll get between different compiler versions. Would it be acceptable to ask users to use an online resource which will compile C to assembly? I found two after a cursory search:

- [C/C++ to Assembly v2](http://assembly.ynh.io/)
- [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: With the chars/instructions formula, the score can approach 0 (e.g. use C macros that, when nested N times, generate 2^N instructions). Also, make it clear that linked libraries don't count.

Comment: @ugoren I'm confused about what you mean by chars/instructions, maybe I should have written instructions/characters instead of 1/characters * instructions? Noted about the linked libraries.

Comment: `define DUP(x) x x` and `DUP(DUP(DUP(DUP(DUP(DUP(x++;))))))` - this duplicates `x++` 64 times. Add another `DUP` and you get 128 times.

Comment: I caught my mistake. The score can approach infinity, not zero. Still, I think, a problem.

Comment: @ugoren Probably too many straightforward abuses to bar them all, eh?

Answer (score 1):

### Off-topic bullshit detector

You run a blog about astronomy and for each post there is an area for comments, where people post comments. So, when you post news about the discovery of a new exoplanet, quickly there are some people commenting about its habitability or about the methods using for their detection, and you do answer those comments, very nice.

You already have a very good spam detector that handles people who tries to post links to viagra-selling sites, so you do not worry with these.

But there is always people who you really hate and makes you very tired. People who insists to post comments that every astronomer is tired and angry to see:

- Comments about creationism.
- Comments about ancient astronauts theory.
- Comments about religion arguing that instead of looking to the sky, people should look for God.
- Comments claiming that this is all a big lie made up by governments around the world, and in fact the man never went to the Moon and the Earth is flat.
- Comments about planet Nibiru, planet Hercolobus, planet X, planet Nemesis and similars.
- Comments about Mayan, Sumerian, or Nostradamus profecies about the end of the world in any particular date.
- Comments about the CIA hiding ETs in Area 51 captured from Roswell and similar stuff.
- Comments about conspiracies by secret groups controlling or willing to control the world, like the Illuminati, the Masonry, the New World Order, and similars.
- Useless flamewar comments that happens when people from two different groups in the previous categories disagree one with the other, posting comments that makes you sometimes doubt that intelligent life exists on Earth.

Your task is: Create a complete program that receives as input a text comment limited to 300 characters and outputs Yes/No, 0/1, Approve/Reject or something similar, rejecting the bullshit comments and accepting the valid ones.

Further, we have a few restrictions:

- As a policy of your company, everyone may comment any post at will, without the need of prior registration, so you can't build some sort of reputation barrier system for this.
- You can't also make comments be approved by other frequent commenters based in some reputation system. This happens because your competitor did that and the result was that the people that you want to avoid managed to take over the site being the ones with the most reputation and thus completely ruining your competitor's site. So, your boss decided that you should not build a reputation system.
- No use of external resources in the internet.
- You are allowed to save files in the disk or to use a database (please do not abuse this rule).
- If you do need, you can add a training program to pre-populate the program data.
- Your algorithm must be deterministic and consistent. I.E, in a given state for a given input, it always produce the same output. So, do not make it randomized nor use as input something like the colors of the pixels in the screen, the system clock or similar sources of entropy.
- [Lacking a rule to avoid exploiting the score system by overfitting the test data].

---

Ok, people, what do you think about this question? Good? Bad? Leave a comment.

This is still lack a winning criteria. Don't know if should be [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), some sort of [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) or something else. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is surely out-of-question for this. What do you think?

Further, to make it testable, this will need some sort of corpus which falls in those bullshit categories and some perfectly valid as well. If you do have some suggestion on this, please, drop a comment.

Comment: I could say that people who post anti-creationist comments are just as annoying...

Comment: Are comments about creationism OK when they are replying to comments about extraterrestrial life?

Comment: Why no database access? Having to reimplement a database makes this challenge harder, but not more interesting. Speaking of which, [tag:code-golf] requires hard criteria for accuracy (and absolute accuracy is impossible to achieve here). The usual solution is to use the popularity metric while telling people to strive for accuracy / accuracy and consciseness / accuracy and opacity / ...

Comment: What makes you think the Illuminati won't use their moon-based supercomputer to figure out how to get around your filter?

Comment: @Geobits That is easy: The man never went to the Moon, so couldn't the Illuminati do it either. In fact, it is impossible to go to the Moon because God made the Earth flat and you can imply by the Genesis that ETs do not exists.

Comment: @JanDvorak. Ok, relaxed the databases requeriment.

Comment: @user2509848 Ok, added this: "*Useless flamewar comments that happens when people from two different groups in the previous categories disagree one with the other, posting comments that makes you sometimes doubt that intelligent life exists on Earth.*"

Comment: What? No, Genesis clearly states that aliens are among us. How do you think the Illuminati got started in the first place? I'm pretty sure the "boss" in this scenario is a member anyway. He's clearly going to use your program to figure out the limits of automated bullshit detection. On topic, I like the spirit of this question, and I'd label it a code-challenge.

Comment: @Geobits, yes I think to that it should be a code-challenge, but don't know yet how to score that. If I don't figure out a good scoring system, will default to popularity-contest.

Comment: If you had a corpus, a basic points system seems easiest. +x for each correct reject, -y for each incorrect, something like that. If entries tie on base score, default to either code length of popularity.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it does seem tough to come up with objective scoring unless there are known inputs (i.e. not "Comments about..." but "These 3 sample strings that comment about..."). But then people will just optimize to those inputs, so you'll probably get better & more interesting results if you go the popularity route and leave the detection categories open-ended as they are.

Comment: +1ed Geobits for simultaneously having the same idea I did. Testing corpus is the way to go if you want it objective.

Comment: OK, seems better.

Comment: Basically you're asking for a Bayesian spam filter. The tricky thing is to write a spec for a Bayesian filter which isn't so restrictive that there's no freedom to be creative, isn't so loose that people can cheat, and doesn't require you to keep the test data secret.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, the solution would probably be a Bayesian spam filter, but it does not needs to be. Yes, that spec is somewhat tricky to fine tune. Further, I still need a corpus.

Answer (score 1):

Repost from previous sandbox, I realize this is somewhat similar to the Limerick program abit higher, but this was made before that.

**The Poet's Quine:**

Write a quine with 1 or more rhyme scheme from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme when read. The non-alphanumeric symbols aren't used for rhyming in this scheme (apart from the basic arithmetic signs like plus, minus, times and divided by), neither are comments. Words may be pronounced in any dialect, but it needs to be consistent within the same stanza (no having the first word be pronounced in a Scottish way and the second in a Welsh way).

Contest type would be popularity contest.

Thoughts on this proposal?

Comment: Do you guys think this is ready for posting?

Answer (score 1):

Weighted letters combination to get 2014.

If a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4,...z=26, which letter combinations (in particular order) when operated by any one or two or three or all four of +,-,X,/ (in any order) will give 2014 as the result?

For example, j*t*j+n=10*20*10+14=2014, t*j*j+n=20*10*10+14=2014 and n+j*t*n=14+10*20*10=2014

are three different combinations.

N.B. - max number of consecutive same letters should be 2, see link http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/are-there-any-english-words-containing-the-same-letter-three-times-in-a-row

Comment: This needs a *lot* of work. Firstly, questions which don't take input are almost always improved by generalising them to take a parameter: in this case, 2014 could be the test case rather than a hard-coded constant. You haven't specified what the output should be: do you want a list of *all* solutions (which could be an insanely large list, even if equivalence classes under permutation of arguments are represented by a single element)? Asking for *any* solution has a trivial approach of just building a long sum.

Comment: Then there's the issue of your final constraint and link: it appears to have no relevance at all to the question, unless you previously intended to state that the expression should, once all operators are removed, form an English word. In that case, it would be as well to just provide a link to a dictionary file for Windows users. You should also be aware that your question might be closed as a near-duplicate of one of [these](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1328/194)  [earlier](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6426/194) [questions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18505/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thanx for pointing out the difficulties, I was just playing with this idea, if we choose the word "mathematics", it has 10 places for +,-,* and /, each of the 10 places can have any one of the four operators, that amounts to $4^{10}=1048576$, that's just impractical to find out what just one word "mathematics" adds up to.

Answer (score 1):

Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to convert an image into ASCII art. Essentially, your program has to do precisely what [picascii.com](http://picascii.com/) does.

**Rules**:

- You must take the image from stdin or read it from a file specified in the command line.
- You must output to stdout or to a filename specified in the command line.
- Your program must take input in a format that [ImageMagick supports](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php). You can choose any format you want, however. If you want to read `ppm` images and we have to pass a jpeg through ImageMagick first to use your program, that's fine.
- Given the above, your program itself must use only standard libraries, even for loading the image.
- You must only output printable ASCII characters (that's 32-126 plus CR and LF).
- You can choose in which font or setting your image should be viewed in, e.g. it might look good in a terminal but awful in a stackexchange code block, or vice versa, or maybe it only looks good with Courier New size 12, etc.
- The largest edge of your output must be at least 25 characters and at most 200 characters long.
- Aspect ratio must be preserved as much as possible within one fixed-width character size. e.g. if you have a 400x320 pixel image, and the fixed-width font you're outputting for is 8x13 including spacing, your output must be at least 25x12 characters, or it can be 50x25, 125x62, etc., with a maximum size of 200x98.
- Provide at least two sample inputs & outputs with your submission. Outputs can be stackexchange code blocks or links to paste bins or screenshots of the output viewed in the environment you intended it for, etc.
- Your score is the byte count of your source code. Lowest score wins.

---

However, I want the output to bear some reasonable resemblance to the input. I don't want this to be subjective. I'd rather have a hard limit that people can hack around.

Opening suggestion: maybe something like: given a font size of 8x13, if the image is converted to grayscale and quantized to 8x13 blocks, and your solution is converted to an image, scaled to fit, and also quantized to homogeneous 8x13 blocks where the value of each block is the percentage of filled-in pixels for each block, the average distance between the image blocks and your output blocks must be less than `X`.

Comment: You should delete it from the main site for now because you can't really change the rules once somebody posts an answer.  You can repost it when you think it is ready.

Comment: @hosch250: Good idea, just deleted it. gotta make it a good one!

Comment: @hosch250: The link isn't broken, it's just a deleted question, and can only be viewed by me and the mods. I wanted to not lose the link but it's there in the edit history I guess.

Comment: It is still in your account page too.

Comment: I think this would be quite dull as a code-golf challenge. The optimal solution is to simply read every other line of a [PGM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) file and convert each number into ASCII 32 (space) or 33 ('!') based on some threshold value. Without a code length restriction, we could add more interesting features like [Floyd-Steinberg dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Steinberg_dithering) and matching letter shapes to image features (e.g., using `/` and ``\`` in places where diagonal likes are detected).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Hmm interesting. I was going for making an objective criterion that would make that not the optimal solution, so you'd have to use more than a few characters, but that'd be awkward. Making it a popularity contest would definitely lead to more creative solutions.. I will consider it

Comment: Hello! This looks like a good but abandoned meta post, would you be willing to [offer it for adoption](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60187/abandoned-challenges-up-for-adoption)? (If you want to, you can still post to main.) Due to community guidelines, if you don't respond to this comment in 7 days I have permission to adopt this.

Answer (score 1):

## Tic-tac-toe

Tic-tac-toe is a paper-and-pencil game for two players, played on a 3×3 grid.

### Rules of Tic-tac-toe

- The first player uses X, the second O as a symbol.
- Tic-tac-toe is round-based. So in the first round, X has to place his symbol on any free grid cell, then O has to place his symbol on any free grid cell and so on.
- The game is over when any player manages to get three of his symbols in any row / column or the diagonal. That player has won. So every game has at least 5 turns.
- The game is over when all cells are full. This is a draw. So every game has at most 9 turns.

### Rules of this codegolf

- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). So shortest code wins.
- Every code has to be playable. This means, at first the user has to be able to decide which player he wants to be (first / second or X / O). The other player will be the computer.
- Optimality: The computer has to use the optimal strategy. This means, the computer can never lose (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)).
- Bonus: If you can play it via GUI, you get -200 characters.
- You should provide an ungolfed version

### Background

I've just seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22576322/562769) on StackOverflow where somebody seems to have hard-coded an optimal player and wants to know how to reduce the size of his program. Lets see how far we can get :-)

### Related questions

- [Noughts and Crosses (aka Tic-Tac-Toe)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1054/5240): It seems to be exactly the same question, but optimality was not required
- [3D Tic Tac Toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15573/5240)
- [The Tic-tac-toe Games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22494/5240): n<sup>d</sup> tic-tac-toe
- [Lose at tic-tac-toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4368/5240)
- [The Tic Tac Toe Dictionary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1065/5240)
- [quine-ish tic-tac-toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11759/5240)

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [this proposed question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi/1323#1323)?  I am not saying that I think that people are wrong in +1ing this and -1ing mine, I just hope to find out how I could have improved it.

Comment: @kitcar2000 it may simply be because yours was posted later. It would have been useful if the downvoter has posted a constructive comment...

Comment: @kitcar2000 I also think that time is important. Why did you add another proposal?

Comment: @moose Sorry, I accidentally undeleted it.

Answer (score 1):

## A Brief Mystery of Time

Given a cron schedule, when will the job next run? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The schedule is supplied as the usual 5 part schedule (to be fleshed out with the full spec). Support for JAN-DEC, SUN-SAT is not required - just numeric schedules - however support for ',','/' and '*' are required. You are not allowed to use the network, or external libraries/programs that implement scheduling - eg using cron itself to schedule a job to return the answer. Your answer should return the result before the time in question.

eg `3-59/15 * * * 0,7` ... should return 3 minutes past midnight next Sunday. Output should be expressed as a human-readable date (not just seconds since the epoch, or fractions of a julian day)

Notes: I had a look, we don't seem to have had cron as a puzzle before. There's going to be some choice of implementations I think-certainly between the Kernhigan cron way of iterating over every minute, or nested loops. A valid answer would be to convert the cron spec to a regexp, iterate over the next few years worth of minutes and match the output of `date`, for example. The code in [quartz](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.6/org/quartz/CronExpression.java) shows that you can be amazingly verbose writing this algorithm, but it's not that hard.

As specified, cron will fire at least once every 40 years if the days of the month are valid-28 years if there's no intervening century year. Unsure whether to say that the input will always produce an event, since validation is easy.

Another variant might be to ensure the solution works for the entire 40 year cycle, by saying the start/date time is input (in some format) and then providing example output. This would save me having to debug the entries, because I could pose the edge cases as tests.

My first try at posing a question.

Comment: In order to make this properly testable, it would probably be sensible to make it take the "current" datetime as an input rather than reading it from the clock. E.g. your example won't return 3 minutes past midnight next Sunday if run on a Sunday before 23:03.

Comment: Yep @PeterTaylor, that's the variant question at the bottom. I agree - it's not only easier to test, but easier to judge the answers because I can tell you the cases I want answered.

Answer (score 1):

Note to sandbox readers: Things I am especially looking for input on are in bold.

## David and Goliath

You are David, fighting Goliath in a turn based game. Can you kill Goliath?

- Goliath is big. He is a *3x3* monster, and fast... but not very maneuverable.
- David is maneuverable, but not very fast. He does have a slingshot, though.

### Goliath's turn

- Goliath may only move in a straight line, up, down, left, right, or 45 degree diagonal (e.g. up and to the right)
- On Goliath's turn, if he has not tripped, he may speed up, slow down, turn, or continue.

  - Continue: Goliath goes in the same direction at the same rate.
  - Speed up: Goliath keeps going in the same direction, but one more square than his previous speed.
  - Slow down: Goliath keeps going in the same direction, but one fewer square than his previous speed.
  - Turn: As *slow down*, except Goliath also turns 45 degrees.
- *Speed zero exception:* there is no such thing as speed zero. If Goliath moved at speed 1 in any direction last turn, he may move at speed 1 in any other direction he chooses.
- If Goliath has tripped, it takes him 1 turn to stand up. **Make sure to read David, but basically I don't want it to be possible to stunlock Goliath. This needs work, suggestions appreciated**
- Goliath is *greedy*. He will move whatever move gets his center square to be the shortest distance in total squares from David. Ties will be broken in the following order:

  - Goliath is an angry beast, he always wants to move faster if he can. He will move at the fastest possible speed. *Note:* this is only used to break ties. If his speed is 4 and he is exactly 3 squares away from David, he will move 3 squares.
  - Goliath prefers not to turn.

### David's turn

This is where your ingenuity comes in. It is your job to program a David algorithm (**Is this too much? Would a user interface be a better question?**) to defeat Goliath.

Here are David's movement rules:

- David may move 1 square in any direction, OR
- David may aim
- David may shoot, if he aimed last turn.

### Other details

- All distances in this problem are considered [Chebyshev Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)

  - Animating the game in text or curses, etc. should look similar to a roguelike.
- Bullets move effectively instantaneously. However, they will only trip Goliath if they are lined up with his center square

  - **Bullets only move in straight lines (the same way Goliath moves?) Is this best?**
- Every time you shoot Goliath, he takes one damage.
- It takes 3 bullets to kill Goliath. (**Or more? or less?**)
- Goliath will kill David if any part of him overlaps with David's square.

### The game board

David and Goliath are fighting on the surface of a Torus (i.e. a flat map that wraps east-west and north-south). Goliath CAN see over the edge of the game board.

### Your job:

Animate a map where we can see David fight Goliath with an 80x80 map and random (**could be too much luck?**) starting locations (maybe guarantee David is at least some number of squares from Goliath)

### Scoring:

**Not sure here:**

- **Most kills in 10000 turns?**
- **Fastest kill?**
- **Golf of a program that animates and shows a combat between David and Goliath where David wins?**

**Other concerns:**

- **I'm concerned David is too slow. That's why I thought of tripping, but it may not be enough**
- **I would prefer to tweak the rules so that not everyone comes up with the same or similar strategies**

ALL input is appreciated, from minor changes to big ones.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I want Goliath's behavior to be mostly deterministic (only if there are no tiebreakers left), the creativity in this problem should be in how you choose to program David.

Comment: Does Goliath have a top speed? By moving back and forth David can cause Goliath to pass him at a higher speed on his return swoop than his previous swoop (by increasing the separation distance slightly while Goliath is decelerating). This allows David to accelerate Goliath to arbitrary speeds. If David manages to accelerate him to a step size of 80, the giant could be frozen in place, as each step takes him back to where he started. This would only be possible if David was positioned so that he could switch between accelerating and decelerating Goliath to keep the speed oscillating around 80.

Comment: On the problem of tiebreakers with Goliath's behaviour being deterministic: If the initial positions are chosen randomly each time, then simply running a few more games per tied winner should break the tie for any player that cannot consistently reach 100%. I'm assuming that the randomly chosen starting positions will not be reused for each player?

Comment: Since this is mostly deterministic, someone may program a player that has 100% success. Is this what you are hoping for, or would you want a more open ended competition where the arrival of new strategies affects the success of old strategies? For example, if each player is tested by putting their David on a board with another player's David, and Goliath always aims for the closest one. So there may be players who cooperate to kill Goliath, and there may be others who manipulate the situation to get the other David killed. This would avoid everyone converging on the same optimum solution.

Comment: Goliath does not have a top speed, but Goliath wants to STOP on David's square. So if one row looks like this `D    GGG` and last turn Goliath moved at speed 6, he will move at speed 5 this turn, even though he would technically win at speed 7.

Comment: @githubphagocyte Your idea about multiple Davids with Goliath going for the closest David is a good one. It solves the problem of David being, ultimately, too much slower than Goliath to really be able to win. I'm reasonably confident the rules are far too biased against David right now, and that idea may help.

Comment: I understand the rough idea of Goliath aiming to decelerate to zero by the time he reaches David's position. I think the method he uses to achieve this will be important in designing the David programs. Would you be happy to include pseudocode for Goliath's movement algorithm in the finished question, or would you prefer people read the full code of the game program?

Comment: Is there a preferred language? Or a defined interface open to any language? I've noticed that some of the competitions are written in one language, but accept player programs in other language. Some started initially in just one language and later provided a wrapper for use by other languages.

Comment: I'm not convinced that David is necessarily at such a disadvantage. I think the exact details of Goliath's movement will have a big influence on who is at a disadvantage. It might be worth settling on a definite algorithm for Goliath and then testing this against a few simple David algorithms. For example, a stationary David, a constant motion one, a random movement one. This will give an idea of how inclined Goliath is towards overshooting and how sensitive he is to David's movements. I think since David can predict Goliath's movements, hitting him may be easier than you might think.

Comment: If you want to see lots of competing strategies then my recommendation would be to make this a king of the hill competition rather than a golf contest. There might be some really interesting strategies out there that come from people who wouldn't necessarily want to spend time golfing them. I'd rather see all the strategies, from the golfers and non golfers...

Comment: Avoiding stunlock:   David or Goliath could be moved to a different location when Goliath is tripped, so that Goliath is no longer in the right position to be shot at without David moving first (assuming the shots are only permitted when Goliath is in one of the 8 compass directions).   David could have a waiting period to reload before he can fire again. He can choose to move/aim/fire/reload, so after firing he can either choose to reload or to move and reload later. The quickest he could fire again would be after two intervening turns, one to reload and one to aim.

Comment: @githubphagocyte lots of great stuff here but I'm traveling this week so my response time will likely be slow. I don't like the idea of requiring a language though. I'll keep thinking about it, keep up the great ideas!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. No rush since it's still in sandbox - take as long as it needs to get it ready...

Answer (score 1):

### Divisibility testing

This question is related to another [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/517429/6876) question:

[image]

### Your task

Write a program that tries to find such an *n*. This question is a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge.

### Format of your answer

Your answer should include

- a title of the format "## [Programming language]: [seconds] seconds"
- the code you were using
- instructions how to run / compile it on Linux Mint (which is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian) - if it does not run on Linux and seems to be better than existing solutions, I will search a Windows computer
- Execution time on your computer for n < 20,000
- CPU of your computer. If it's an Intel CPU: please link to [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/). You can find your CPU with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

### What could be done

The following Python code needs 229.21s seconds to execute on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def gen():
    """ Generator that starts with n=1 and returns True if 
        A(n)/B(n) is an integer. Otherwise, it returns False.
    """
    num = 0
    den = 0
    k = 1
    while True:
        num += k**k
        den += k
        yield num % den == 0
        k += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1
    for number in gen():
        if number:
            print("n = %i works!" % n)
            if n > 1:
                break
        if n == 30000:
            print("No solution found.")
            break
        n += 1
```

Things that could probably improved are:

- Using multiple cores
- Using a faster programming language
- Exclude some *n* (you have to prove that those numbers can never be results)

Note: When you find some *n* that can be excluded, you get a time bonus. The number of seconds you get as a time bonus is the number of seconds that it speeds up my Python implementation from above.

- Prove that there cannot be any *n > 1* so that A(n)/B(n) is an integer. You will win if you find that. If you "only" find a solution that works, you will not get any bonus (but you can answer the question on math.SE :-) )
- Find a faster way to calculate the hyperfactorial A(n).

### Testing system

I have an [Intel P6200 CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz) (2.13 GHz, 2 cores, 3 MB cache). I will run your code on my system to make it comparable. I will take the time this way:

```
time python testit.py
```

### Tags I will use:

(This will not be part of the question, of course.)

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Comment: A(n) is not actually the hyperfactorial - it's a kind of related summand, but the hyperfactorial is the product of those terms. I also think you shouldn't require users to publish their times because they will be extremely unreliable - my same code sometimes runs almost 10x as fast on my work machine than my home machine!

Comment: Why ask people how fast code ran on their machine? Different computers run at different speeds.

Comment: Can I take ownership of this question and post a completed question on the main site. Let me know in 1 week

Comment: @george Sure. Please let a link here so that I can have a look at the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a text-art table

Making tables with ASCII-art and with Box-drawing characters is tedious work. Let's simplify this work by automating it with a program:

**Input and Output:**

The first line of input signify's whether the user wants an ASCII table or a Box-drawn one. This is simply given as a number: `1` for ASCII, `0` for Box-drawing.

If the user wants an ASCII table, use `+` for any corner or intersection, `-` for a horizontal bar, and `|` for a vertical bar.

If the user wants a Box-drawn table, you must use these characters (the light characters from [Box-drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)):

```
┌
└
┐
┘
├
┬
┴
┤
─
│
┼
```

The next lines of input will be tab delimited, newline delimited entries. Newlines delimit rows of the entry, and tabs delimit columns. If the user wants multiple columns on a cell, this will be delimited by a `\`. `\\` asks for a literal `\`. If the user wants to join two cells, this will be indicated by `\=`.

You will output a table that meets the user-defined specifications. Space-buffer the cell content, that is, prepend and append a space when inserting it in the table. When centering the text, prefer prepending spaces to appending them. Shrink the leftmost cell possible when there is a choice. Columns always line up, whether the lines form from a `\` or a tab.

For example, this input (`→` is a tab):

```
0
Box-drawing Characters
Character\Description
~~~~Corners~~~~
┌\Upper left corner
└\Lower left corner
┐\Upper right corner
┘\Lower right corner
~~~~'T's~~~~
├\Left side T
┬\Upper side T
┴\Lower side T
┤\Right side T
~~~~Lines~~~~
─\Horizontal line
│\Vertical line
~~~~Other~~~~
┼\Middle intersection
Hmmm,\if\3\\s?
This\Is\The\End
```

Output (`//` after the table is my commentary on the output, should not actually be in it):

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│      Box-drawing Characters     │
├───────────┬─────────────────────┤
│ Character │     Description     │
├───────────┴─────────────────────┤
│         ~~~~Corners~~~~         │
├───────────┬─────────────────────┤ //The line for the column split lines up with the previous lines
│     ┌     │  Upper left corner  │ //This line was too long, so the previous lines got longer to accommodate it.
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     └     │  Lower left corner  │
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     ┐     │  Upper right corner │ //Too long again
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     ┘     │  Lower right corner │
├───────────┴─────────────────────┤
│           ~~~~'T's~~~~          │
├───────────┬─────────────────────┤
│     ├     │     Left side T     │
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     ┬     │     Upper side T    │
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     ┴     │     Lower side T    │
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     ┤     │     Right side T    │
├───────────┴─────────────────────┤
│          ~~~~Lines~~~~          │
├───────────┬─────────────────────┤
│     ─     │   Horizontal line   │
├───────────┼─────────────────────┤
│     │     │     Vertcal line    │
├───────────┴─────────────────────┤
│          ~~~~Other~~~~          │
├───────────┬─────────────────────┤
│     ┼     │ Middle intersection │ //Too long, so other lines adjusted
├───────┬───┴┬────────────────────┤
│ Hmmm, │ if │        3\s?        │ //Because the user wants to divide into 3, the cells don't line up with the previous ones.
├──────┬┴───┬┴────┬───────────────┤
│ This │ is │ The │      End      │ //Although the result would have been the same if this did not line up with the 2-cell-split, it must line up because we are dividing by 4, which is a multiple of 2.
└──────┴────┴─────┴───────────────┘
```

This input:

```
1
hello→World→!
\Lorem→Ipsum.\Quick→Fox
\=\=
This is\ → the\ last→row.\
```

Produces this as an output:

```
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|       hello      |      World     |    !    |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
|         |  Lorem | Ipsum. | Quick |   Fox   |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
|                                             |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+------+--+
| This is |        |   the  |  last | row. |  |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+------+--+
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

---

Meta:

Is my specification well defined enough yet?

Comment: I don't think I understand the layouting rules. Please provide more examples or some pseudocode. Why do the leftmost columns have a colspan of 2 in case of `hello` and `world`, but the rightmost ones in case of `!` and `Fox`? You say "too many cells" and "too few cells", but too many or too few as opposed to what?

Comment: I think this would actually be most interesting if you accepted input in basic html format. It would be like writing an ASCII html table renderer. I think that would be super interesting

Comment: @Cruncher The purpose was so that it is easy for anyone to create a table. I want to be able to quickly type something and get a table back. HTML ruins that.

Comment: In anycase, the challenge boils down to converting some form of markup into a table. Using a simpler markup gives you less power. In this case, as @JanDvorak mentions, you have a problem with colspan. There's a lot of specification that has to go into a problem like this.

Comment: @Cruncher Yes. I need to go and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## Game similar to [the Fifteen Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/solve-the-15-puzzle-the-tile-sliding-puzzle)

Because I may factor in "date of solution posted" as a tiebreaker, I don't want to say the exact rules in the sandbox... but the exact rules aren't the reason I'm putting this in the sandbox.

Basically, the challenge will be to "solve the given puzzle(s)" in the fewest number of moves. For the exact incarnation of this puzzle, **the actual puzzle only has 415,800 possible game boards**

The problem is scoring:

- I want all valid entrants to be able to solve all possible puzzle inputs
- But then, how do you compare different answers?
- Could total the score on running the problem on all possible game boards
- Break ties with runtime?
- Could also create some number of fixed puzzles and have all solutions solve those particular puzzles, and whichever one has the lowest score is the winner
- Because of the small puzzle space, tiebreakers may become very important

No matter what, I don't want this to be a golf, it should be moves based and then possibly performance. All thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Array Calculator

Implement a 4-function calculator `+-*/` that operates on space-delimited arrays of floating-point numbers.

```
1 2 3 4+5 6 7 8
6.0 8.0 10.0 12.0
```

It should evaluate the functions right-to-left, in the manner of APL. In other words, among the functions there is no precedence of any kind.

```
1 2+3 4*5 6+7 8
=>
1 2+3 4*12 14
=>
1 2+36 56
=>
37.0 58.0
```

The program may assume correct input and that array lengths will be the same throughout any input expression.

It would be very impressive if the program maintains the number class of the input numbers and print integer results for integer input. But this is not necessary. It is acceptable to fold all numbers to floating-point. The program may assume a maximum array length of 10.

#### Questions

Should it be more complicated? Or is it okay to keep it simple?

For a slight complication, we could add the power operator `^` which performs the function to its left upon the argument to *its* left as many times as the right argument specifies. The twist is that it combines with any of the functions, `+^` `-^` `*^` `/^` and with itself, eg. `+^^` == `*^` == `pow()`, `+^` == `*`. `/^` would be identity of the left argument. `-^` would oscillate between zero and the left argument.

Comment: How will error results be handled? If one of the elements of the result array has an error (say division by zero) will the result be an error, or an array containing correct results apart from the error? That is, should the error cause complete failure or just failure for the affected elements of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure. Which would be more fun for participants? I suppose it should print a message and abort the whole expression. ... But for `0÷0` APL defines the result 1. As well as `x*0` (where `*` is exponentiation) ...  so maybe it needs identity elements for the functions, too.

Comment: As the rules differ between applications, you'd need to specify either a strict rule for each ambiguity, or a list of acceptable outcomes. Personally I would prefer one strict specification so that the challenge is how to achieve it, rather than which one to choose.

Comment: I don't see `x*^0` (exponentiation in your specified notation) as a problem as this should return 1. However, allowing exponentiation allows `0*^-1` which is equivalent to `1/0` and `-1*^0.5` which is the square root of minus one. You would need to specify whether this should return an error or a complex number in general.

Comment: Rather than end up writing a long specification for your calculator, it might be worth stating that its behaviour should match some existing system which has a clear unambiguous specification already. Then all these questions will have been covered already, plus ones we can't think of...

Answer (score 1):

## Run-as-you-type disaster

[Swift playground](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/ExploringandEvaluatingSwiftCodeinaPlayground/ExploringandEvaluatingSwiftCodeinaPlayground.html) is a programming environment with a peculiar feature that it executes code as you type. This means that when you type [`system("cd ~; rm -rf *")`](http://www.mactrast.com/2014/06/careful-apples-new-swift-playground-run-type-can-dangerous/), it will remove all files from your home directory without waiting for you to save the file, compile and execute it manually. Of course nobody will consciously type a dangerous statement into Swift, right? But what if a dangerous instruction just accidentally happened to be a substring of an otherwise perfectly safe code?

Your task is to write a piece of code:

- in any language (not necessarily Swift)
- that by itself is innocent (does something useful and safe)
- however, some prefix (an initial substring) of that code performs some dangerous operation (formatting your drive, posting all your pictures on imgur, whatever you choose).

A [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) question.

Comment: Add an [tag:underhanded] tag to this.

Comment: I don't think this should be posted, as people could easily accidentally execute it. It's just too dangerous.

Comment: @Jwosty: what if the "dangerous operation" part was changed to "suddenly draws a christmas tree" (or sth similar)?

Comment: That would be a different contest, so I would post that as another answer

Answer (score 1):

## String Subtraction without Converting to Numbers

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Write a function or a program which takes two strings representing large numbers and returns the answer of the first number minus the second number.

**Input**

- Two strings each matching the regular expression `-?[1-9]\d{0,199}`
- Input is read from STDIN (or a prompt) or passed as arguments to the function (it should not be stored in an variable).

**Output**

- A string matching the regular expression `-?[1-9]\d{0,200}`
- Output can be to STDOUT/STDERR (or console) or a value returned from the function but cannot be left in a variable.

**Rules**

- Use of the [Standard "loopholes"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9275) is not allowed.
- Lowest score wins.

**Scoring**

- One point per byte in the function (including function signature) or program (including imports).
- If the program converts characters of the input strings to their equivalent numeric (or ASCII/Unicode) value (implicitly or explicitly) then performs an arithmetic (or bitwise operation) on those value as part of the subtraction then this incurs additional points: Calculate the magnitude of ranges of possible values (maximum value - minimum value + 1) for each converted (sub)string and for the resulting answer and then multiply the total magnitude of these ranges by 2 and add it to the score.
- I.e. The (incomplete) JavaScript `function(x,y){for(i=x.length-1,j=y.length-1;i>=1&&j>=1;i--,j--){a=x.charCodeAt(i);b=y.charCodeAt(j);c=a-b;/* do something with "value" */}}` would score:

  - 135 characters (bytes);
  - The variables `i` and `j` do not store character values from the strings so do not add any extra points;
  - `a=x.charCodeAt(i)` stores an ASCII value of a single numeric digit (i.e. ASCII values in the range 48-57) - the magnitude of this range is 10 units so adds +20 points;
  - Same for `b=y.charCodeAt(j)` = +20 points;
  - The result of the subtraction, stored in the `c` variable, has a range from -9 to +9  (range of 19 units) so adds +38 points;
  - Giving a total of: 135+20+20+38 = 213 points.
  - *Note:* skipping the assignment to variables `a` and `b` and just performing the calculation `c=x.charCodeAt(i)-y.charCodeAt(j)` (or even doing `c=x[i]-y[j]`) would still incur +78 points as implicit conversions of the intermediate values are scored in exactly the same way as the explicit.
- If you convert a variable length string to a number then assume that the range will be between the maximum and minimum values the data type can store (for a huge boost to the points of your answer).

Comment: Sounds interesting, but are you sure the regexes are right? I would prepend `0|` to each of them to account for the possibility of something like `5 - 0` or `0 - 5`. Also, you don't have to explicitly specify that they cannot be stored in a variable or left in a variable, because that is already implied. Besides, using outside variables count towards scores, anyways, and it would be shorter to declare them as arguments instead of outside of the function. It's usually the same with returning as well.

Answer (score 1):

Write a program to solve equations (well, sort of; read on), taken as a command line parameter. Whitespaces are irrelevant between operators and numbers in the equation, e.g. `1+2` and `1\t + 2` (where `\t` is a tab) are both fine. There can be any number of variables, but they will always be one lower-case letter. You can assume always exactly two sides of the equation, but the sign can be `=` `>` `≥` `<` or `≤` (don't forget that the sign of an inequality flips when you multiply or divide both sides by a negative number). You must support the following operations:

- `a+b` — addition
- `a-b` — subtraction
- `a*b` — multiplication (cannot appear as `ab`)
- `a/b` — division
- `b^n` — exponentiation, and you can assume that:

  - `n` will never be a variable
  - `n` will always be an integer, and remember that a negative `n` means `1/(b^-n)`
- `a*(b*c-d)` - parenthesis and the order of operations (PEMDAS)

Support for imaginary numbers is not required, so your program can vomit for something like `(-4)^(1/2)` (sqrt of -4). Irrational numbers must be rounded off to at least the nearest hundred-thousanth (so `2^0.5` becomes `1.41421`), and you can apply the same to fractions if you so choose. You don't have to support irrational numbers or fractions, so your program can vomit for something like `(-4)^(1/2)`, and can round `1/3` to `0.33333` (5 decimal places). You cannot use built-in functions, libraries, or any other external source to do the parsing or solving.

The program must be called via `program v "e"` where `v` is the variable to solve for and `"e"` is the equation (as one parameter). Assume that `v` will appear in the equation. Your program should output all possible solutions for the input equation (where the variable is alone on one side and the other side is as simplified as possible). Here are some example equations and a possible solution for each:

- `a*(3-1)=1` for `a` -> `a*2=1` -> (output) `a=1/2` or `a=0.5`
- `x*y/2-5>1` for `x` -> `x*y/2>6` -> `x*y>12` -> (output) `x>12/y`
- `x^(3/2)=2*x` for `x` -> `x^(3/2)/x=2` -> `x^0.5=2` -> (output) `x=4`
- `(x+1)^2=4` for `x` -> `x+1=-2, x+1=2` -> (output) `x=-3, x=1`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: So [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) would win because it would have a score of 0?

Comment: @KyleKanos: Followed closely by any language with an eval function/operator.

Comment: @Dennis: *You cannot use built-in functions, libraries, or any other external source to do the parsing or solving* would seem to block `eval`, unless I'm misreading something.

Comment: @KyleKanos: `eval("entire code goes here");` has two tokens and doesn't violate those rules.

Comment: @Dennis `eval` evaluates expressions, not solve equations. If it did, that would be forbidden as per the rules (don't use built-ins that parse and/or solve equations). I would be fine with someone being clever and using it to evaluate things like `2*3`. Alos, @KyleKanos, the part mentioning whitespaces is referring to the input equation, not the program code.

Comment: @Jwosty: I categorized `eval` into "parsing", but that's not exactly what it does. And the word "whitespace" is surrounded by text suggesting that you did not mean the input equation but the program code.

Comment: @Jwosty: You're missing the point. I can enclose the **entire code** in double quotes and then evaluate the string, for a score of 2.

Comment: @Dennis: ah, I see your point now. However, wouldn't the other [tag:atomic-code-golf] questions address this as well, as it's an issue of any atomic code golf, not this question in particular?

Comment: Also, @KyleKanos: I think I fixed the wording in the beginning. Does it read clearly now?

Comment: My issue with regards to whitespace is in the last sentence. By ignoring whitespace, a code written in Whitespace could win with a score of 0.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Ah, I see. This would just be so much simpler as standard code-golf. I'll change it.

Comment: The atomic code golf tag wiki uses a pretty non-standard definition of token. Aparently, every character in a string is a token. Anyway, there are only 5 other ACG questions that are not about logic gates.

Comment: What does "*Your program should output all possible solutions for the input equation*" mean for equations which can't be rearranged to put the variable alone on one side? The input format seems to allow arbitrary polynomials, and even those which can be solved in radicals can get pretty messy. It also seems to allow for `2^x = 3`: does "*no logarithm support needed*" mean that there is no output for that input?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Alright then, I think it'll just be simplest to allow the program to assume it'll never encounter a variable exponent, and that it'll always be an integer. That makes it somewhat less messy.

Comment: This problem is insanely difficult. Even finding whether a set of multivariable real equals has a solution was a [major  computational breakthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals). I'd suggest restricting the problem to addition, subtraction, and inequalities in a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

## Build a GenericScript Compiler

Your task is to build part of a compiler for the new programming language GenericScript. In this challenge you are only required to check the input source code for syntax errors and not build a running program.

Given the source code for a GenericScript program as input, parse the source code to check that it conforms to the syntax rules for the language. The syntax definition for GenericScript is below. If a part of the source code is found to be invalid, a message must be displayed informing the programmer that there is a mistake.

Since the challenge is for syntax only, you are not required to check for correct usage of variables e.g. use of undeclared variable. Only the syntax rules specified need to be checked.

A bonus will be given if the output message includes the line of code where the problem occurs.

**Win Criteria**

This is code golf. Shortest code wins. Implementing the line number bonus allows you to multiply you score by 0.8 e.g. only 80% of your code length will be counted as your score.

**Syntax**

"C" style whitespace rules apply i.e. multiple whitespace characters are treated the same as a single whitespace character & whitespace is only required in between tokens if it would otherwise cause syntax ambiguity.

```
Program             = Statement
Statement           = Assignment | If | Output | Sequence | While | StringDeclaration | BooleanDeclaration
Assignment          = Identifier "=" (String | Bool); 
StringDeclaration   = "string" Identifier "=" String ";"
BooleanDeclaration  = "bool" Identifier "=" Bool ";"
If                  = "if(" Bool ")" Statement ["else" Statement]
While               = "while(" Bool ")" Statement
Output              = "print(" String ");"
Sequence            = "{" [SequenceContent] "}"
SequenceContent     = Statement [SequenceContent]
Identifier          = {Any sequence of alphanumeric characters with at least 7 characters (all language keywords are shorter than this) }
Bool                = BoolConstant | OperatorAnd | OperatorOr | OperatorNot | StringEquals | BoolEquals | Identifier
BoolConstant        = "true" | "false"
OperatorAnd         = Bool "&&" Bool
OperatorOr          = Bool "||" Bool
OperatorNot         = "!" Bool
StringEquals        = String "==" String
BoolEquals          = Bool "==" Bool
String              = StringConstant | OperatorConcat | Input | Identifier
StringConstant      = "'"StringConstContent"'"
StringConstContent  = "\\" | "\'" | Character [StringConstContent]
Character           = {Any character except for "\" and "'"}
OperatorConcat      = String "&" String
Input               = "read()"
```

**Test Input**

Valid Input:

```
print('What is your name?')
string myInput = read();
print('Hello ' & myInput);
```

Invalid Syntax:

```
If(read() == 'DoTask1')
  print('Executing you'r command');
```

Comment: Wow, that sounds like quite a task. A few issues I can think of: a) you should specify exactly how scoping works. b) your first bonus is a bit hard to nail down - how detailed does the error message have to be? And do the strings for those error messages (or any warnings) count towards the code size? Because then this may just devolve into people using ridiculous shorthand for notifications and claiming they are sufficient. c) Are you 100% sure your grammar is complete, correct and consistent? d) You provide a grammar but no definition of the semantics of the individual constructs. (continued)

Comment: Most of the symbols have an implied meaning, but there doesn't seem to be a specification what any individual literal, operator or function is supposed to do, so *any* compiler that checks the syntax could claim it compiled the program correctly based on some arbitrary spec.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I quite like the idea, but it seems to be a bit too much of a mammoth project to work well on PPCG - the main problem being that this is very prone to little mistakes not being caught before the challenge goes on main and people start working on it... which just leads to frustration all around.

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for your feedback. I have simplified the chalenge and simplified the syntax rules.

Comment: Is it case-sensitive? If yes, then your syntax list contains some case-changes.

Answer (score 1):

### License Plate Recognition (LPR): fix errors

A License Plate reading software often mistakes some characters. Some of the commonly mistaken pairs of characters are O,0 I,1 4,9 and S,5.
Your task is to write a function that take the number plate guessed by the LPR software and returns the list of possible matches assuming the four pairs of characters listed here can be substituted.

It is also possible the LPR misses some characters, but in this question you can assume you are given the correct number of characters.

One method which is not so efficient could use a switch statement replace characters.
Example function declaration would be:

```
List<string> equivalent(string plateNumber);
```

The function format is up to you.

Sample input:

```
SSH389
ONC073
```

Output:

```
SSH389, S5H389, 5SH389, 55H389
ONC073, 0NC073, ONCO73, 0NCO73
```

This is code golf, shortest code wins.

Posting in sandbox for review.

Answer (score 1):

## Voice recognition: "yes" or "no"?

Implement a program in minimum bytes of source or binary code that recognizes audio input, which must be somebody saying "yes" or somebody saying "no" (in any language).

Standard "no longer funny loopholes" apply.

Audio files can be supplied from stdin (as raw or compressed audio in any format), or read from file. Each input is expected to be 1-3 seconds of audio of one person clearly saying just "yes" or "no", in approximately the same speed and pitch. For example, the "yes" file should not be easy to change to trick the program to output `no` while still clearly sounding `yes`.

External libraries and builtins: only functions accepting constant-sized input (i.e. `sin`, `pow`) can be used, not FFT, for example.

Questions:

1. Should it be code-golf or popularity contest?
2. Should I provide test cases?
3. Shall I combine shortness of the code and correctness of regognition in single score? Or limit one of them?

Comment: **1)** Provide the audio files. If code golf, provide a *large* number of samples. **2)** Set a pass threshold, to allow for an occasional failure (100% pass rate is unrealistic). **3)** Drop the "no standard loopholes" tag line. I am so tired of seeing that on every single post. It's more of an eyesore than the loopholes themselves. /rantoff

Comment: Is it possible to both have `'yes' and 'no' may be said in any language` and `code-golf`? I can't provide samples for all languages...

Comment: If you cannot provide samples for every language, then you should not be running a competition with every language.

Comment: What's better: 1. just stick to English, 2. Provide as many languages as I can and limit to them?

Comment: I would be biased if I said limit it to English. There's also this [policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), but I don't think it applies to interpreting audio files. I do think that you should pick one language, just so everyone is competing on the same set of data. The language you choose is really up to you.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're after real voice recognition or just the ability to distinguish two files. If you're after real voice recognition, there needs to be some training process ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FFRoYhTJQQ is from a comedy programme, but it's a good illustration of a genuine problem). If you just want to distinguish two files, it's no challenge at all.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, So two sets should be provided (learning and test), to avoid just hardcoding hashes?

Comment: I think it's also necessary to require that the program not hard-code any data at all, to prevent people pre-tuning it against the test data. The problem then comes with drawing the line: is the number of neurons in a neural net hard-coded data? Or the function used by the neuron? I think it's a good idea, but hard to fit into the PCCG model.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, `is the number of neurons in a neural net hard-coded data?` -> ["nothing up my sleeve" numbers?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number)

Comment: I don't see the relevance.

Comment: I've just written a [Perl script that generates WAV files from text-to-speech calls with random parameters](http://pastebin.com/ReD09gBj). It needs OS X to run, but I can generate the files for you if you like. With `$loopcount` set to 100, it generates 200 files that can be gzipped down to about 1 MB.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, I plan yo just record me saying "yes... no... yes... no... ..." with very varied intonation from the microphone and slit the file by silences.

Comment: @Vi. So much the better :-)

Comment: Shall I keep both training and scoring sets public?

Comment: Would you mind deleting this one, now that the sandbox is merged and the challenge has been posted?

Comment: Do you mean blanking the answer (preserving the history) or actually deleting? Maybe the discussion in the comments can stick around for somebody who also want to make a "recognition of whatever" golf, for mentioning common pitfalls. Is there any "sandbox archive"?

Answer (score 1):

Mac file explorer is so "Great" that it deserve to be replaced.

Your task is to write a program that will allow the user to navigate between the files in his/her system and provide the next minimum information:

- file name
- is it a file or a folder

Rulles:

- Any input allowed as long as it's **not Keyboard**. So, you can use voice recognition, mouse or what ever input you want.
- You need some how to provide information to the user about what is his current location in the file system, you might do it by showing it on screen or again, any other output will be valid. (you can print him where is he now).
- Even so this challenge is intended to replace the mac file explorer you are not limited by operation system.

This is a popularity contest, so the most voted answer wins. It's not limited by time. The first winner will be declared within two weeks.

Comment: Some comments. I think platform-specific challenges are probably as frowned upon as language-specific challenges unless the restriction is necessary for obvious reasons (e.g. OP hosting a KotH and being limited to one platform). Furthermore, for a code-golf challenge this is way underspecified. What constitutes a valid program? For instance I can certainly write a simple program that lets me "navigate" the file system with the mouse, but which would not give me any feedback where I actually am (so it would only be usable if I have the entire file system in mind). (ctd.)

Comment: As it currently stands, such a program would fulfil the spec, but it's probably not what you had in mind. So either make it a popularity contest, which might be interesting here. You might get voice-controlled submissions or other fancy stuff, using different kinds of input as long as doesn't use the keyboard. Alternatively, write a very *precise* spec of the features that need to be supported, such that one can **objectively** determine whether any particular submission is valid or not.

Comment: @m.buettner I liked your suggestions. Please tell me what do you think now.

Comment: Yes sounds much better, but please wait for some more feedback from others before posting it on main. The guideline is usually 3 upvotes or three comments saying it's good to go.

Comment: Even popularity contests should have specs. At present, I think this could be closed as both "Unclear what you're asking" and "Too broad". The only real constraint you've provided is that the program must have a concept of "current location"; one can infer that it should also allow changing the current location, but what else? Listing file names? Listing file properties? Executing executable files?  Opening data files with an appropriate application? (NB That would restrict the possible OSes). Copying? Renaming? Deleting? Etc.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Got you, how about now?

Comment: If your goal is really to get something *better* than the existing file explorer then you may be disappointed, but as a spec goes that's better.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hell no. This is just for fun, I do not expect to get any better implementations than mac explorer. If I ask for it, it just make this question boaring

Answer (score 1):

### Bugs Bunny Word Chain

*Modified 'word chain' puzzle / popularity contest*

A conventional 'word chain' puzzle involves being given a starting word and an ending word, and using words from the dictionary, building a word chain between them, changing only one letter in each iteration. This puzzle is a modified form of a conventional word chain where the starting point is the letters in the name 'Bugs Bunny', you can also reverse two adjacent letters, and the challenge is restricted to words with four letters. And... the code should be convoluted and crazy-looking.

In a single iteration, you may do only *one* of the following:

- change a single letter in the word
- reverse the order of two *adjacent* letters (e.g. "brat" can become "bart," but *not* "trab").

In addition to these rules, you must also:

- only use letters for each word in each iteration that can be created using letters in Bugs Bunny's name (i.e. "BUGSBUNNY", no space). Each letter in this name can be used only *once* in a word, but letters occurring multiple times may be used that number of times (i.e. sampling without replacement).
- ensure the words are dictionary words—they cannot be nonsensical (in this case it is fine to simply store the acceptable words in an array/list/whatever data structure you choose since there are only 16 possible combinations according to most ['Scrabble' tools](http://www.wineverygame.com/wbg.php?letters=bugsbunny&lettersh=bugsbunny&preffix=&preffixh=&oa=or&suffix=&suffixh=&submit=Find%20Words&pr=)). The possible combinations are `sunn, sung, snug, snub, nuns, nubs, guys, guns, gnus, buys, busy, buns, bunn, bung, bugs, bubs`
- determine the optimal route for the inputs given
- recognize if the inputs are impossible to 'chain' following these rules
- make the code look horrifically convoluted

The solution should work given any two *possible* inputs.

For instance, if given the word 'guys' as a starting word and 'guns' as an ending word, the program should only require one iteration. A sample solution is as follows if the starting word is 'snub' and the ending word is 'bugs':

> `snub snug sung bung buns bugs` (five iterations)

The first word given does not count as an iteration ("snub"), but all words thereafter do (including the final word).

Thus iterations are calculated as *n*—1. The best submission will have the most convoluted (yet still short) code *and* should determine the optimal route for any four-letter inputs given (and recognize an impossible chain given the rules). This is a popularity contest.

Comment: If there's only 16 words, please include them in the challenge, or someone will go ahead and use less or more words because he found them in a different dictionary. Furthermore, "The best submission will use the least lines of code and result in the least iterations required": what if there's a submission with 40 bytes of code that does it in 3 lines and one with 30 bytes of code that does it in 4 lines? Which one wins? Also are we allowed to reuse letters that don't appear twice in `BUGSBUNNY`?

Comment: @m.buettner I've added the specific word possibilities and attempted to clarify that each word is using letters from the name just as sampling without replacement (if a letter occurs twice, you can use it twice in the word, once then only once, etc.). I'm not sure the best route to go for 'least lines of code'. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: With only 16 words, I'd say you should require all submissions to be optimal and then ask for the shortest code. Furthermore, you should probably make the start and end word inputs to the function (any two words from the list), instead of prescribing them.

Comment: @m.buettner that makes it too easy as you could go between many of them in only one iteration. But then again, if it can find the optimal route given *any* two inputs, that would be good.

Comment: @m.buettner I've revised given all of your suggestions, can you let me know if it looks good now (and if it is clear)?

Comment: Yes looks better. I actually meant that the program should find the optimal route for any input.

Comment: @m.buettner but not upvote-worthy? What can be done to improve it? (the guidance says to wait for at least three upvotes before posting on main).

Comment: Or three comments saying it's good to go. ;) ... Personally I don't know what the introduction has to do with anything. Just seems to bloat up the challenge. Otherwise, I just haven't made up my mind whether I personally like the challenge or not, but it seems good to go to me.

Comment: @m.buettner i.e. the picture or the explanation in paragraph-form, or both?

Comment: both, to be honest

Comment: @m.buettner see update. Is that better?

Comment: yup, have an upvote

Comment: @m.buettner thanks for the input!

Comment: This is quite close to being a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2478/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor it is very close, only here they are restricted to the letters in the name 'BUGSBUNNY' and they can also reverse adjacent letters, which significantly limits the available possibilities.

Comment: @PeterTaylor perhaps this is an extension of that whereby an allowed set of characters is first given (i.e. only using the letters in this sequence, sampling without replacement)?

Comment: This might be interesting as a popularity contest, where the goal was any "bad" code that produced interesting or clever output, and fit legibly into the space provided.  I would love to see what the inventive, sick minds around here come up with.

Comment: @WayneConrad that's actually the idea to some extent. I like it. I will modify accordingly.

Comment: @WayneConrad see update :)

Comment: The ability to reverse letters isn't a very significant change: it just adds a few more edges to the graph. The limited word list is data, not code. I think finding subgrams has been done before too.

Answer (score 1):

## Markdown to HTML converter

### Challenge

Write a program that takes a file name ending in `.md`, `.mkd` or `.markdown` as a command-line argument (or the closest equivalent in your language of choice) and converts it to a valid HTML 5 document.

### Rules

- If an error is detected, you must print an error message and terminate the program with a non-zero exit status.
- The output file name must be the input file name with the extension changed to `.html`.
- You don't have to include a doctype or `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags.
- You must support everything listed in the [CommonMark specification](https://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html), except for embedded HTML and HTML entities.
- You may not use an existing library or similar tool for processing Markdown.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: The spec is notoriously incomplete. This needs a very big set of test cases. I personally favour [Michel Fortin's test cases](https://github.com/michelf/mdtest).

Comment: The test cases themselves won't fit in the post; and there are a small number which won't be appropriate (either because they use the parts of the spec which you've said we don't need to support, or because they're too implementation-dependent). Perhaps the best thing would be for you to fork the git repo, trim it down to the relevant test cases, and link to your fork.

Comment: I just discovered [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/), so I'm using that now.

Comment: That is excellent news. I've been checking for signs of progress on that project every couple of months since Atwood announced the idea on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

## Finding Integer Linear Factors of Integer Polynomials

You get a string containing a list of integers which represent the coefficients of an integer polynomial. E.g. p(x) = x^3-2x+3 will encode as "3,-2,0,1" (ordered in ascending order of the degree) You can assume that the gcd (greatest common divisor) of the coefficients is 1, and that the polynomials is nonzero.

Your task is finding all roots p(x) = 0 where x is an integer.

The output string will consist of two parts, separated with semicolon:

- The first part contains a list of the integer roots in ascending order. (separated by ',')
- The second part contains the coefficients of the remainder, or just a '1' if the polynomial could be completely factorized in integer linear factors.

### Examples

- The polynomial x^4+2x^3-x-2 will encode as "-2,-1,0,2,1". It can be factorized as (x^2+x+1)(x-1)(x+2) so the output will be: "-2,1;1,1,1"
- x^3-x+2 is irreducible will encode as "2,-1,0,1", output will be ";2,-1,0,1"
- -2x^6-2x^5+7x^4+x^3-x^2+2x-6 is a product of two irreducible polynomials (x^2+x-3)(-2x^4+x^2+2), has therefore no integer roots and encodes as "-6,2,-1,1,7,-2,-2" output will be ";-6,2,-1,1,7,-2,-2"
- x-1 will encode as "-1,1" and has the output "1;1"
- 3 will encode as "3" and has the output ";3"

### I/O

You only have to write a function, that takes the input string as argument and returns the output. If this is not available to your language, use an equivalent structure. (function, named block, or named verb)

### Goal

The shortest (correct) solution (in bytes) wins. (codegolf)
Please upvote special and elegant solutions!

EDIT: More examples, assumptions, I/O

Comment: May we assume that the input coefficients are coprime? If not, what are the implications for the output? Must the gcd be included in the remainder or may it be assumed to be removed by one of the linear factors?

Comment: Also, you describe the input and output formats; it would be good to say explicitly that the coefficients are ordered from constant coeff to leading coeff. What you don't describe is the I/O mechanism. Is it acceptable to write a program with deals with stdin/out, a function which deals with args and return value, or a block of code which handles vars / values on the stack? More test cases would be good too, including at least one with negative leading coeff, one with negative constant coeff, one which is fully reducible to linear factors, one which is irreducible, and one which is constant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for those points: Yes I think I should exclude the case that the factors are not coprime, (gcd of all factors (together) is 1). What do you think would be a good input/output mechanism? I think a function  that accepts and returns the strings would be appropriate. 

Regarding the examples: Up to now I did not consider providing test cases, but of course I need to! I want to point out one tricky part of the task as it is now: A polynomial can be a product of two irreducible polynomials, so that the polynomial itself is not irreducible but also doesn't have linear factors.

Comment: [continuing] Do you think that this is too difficult? I also thought about reducing the task to polynomials which have maximum one irreducible factor. I mean quite a bit of math is required in order to determine the irreducibility. A way simpler task would be the factorization of a polynomial that consists only of linear factors...

Comment: True, you should have a test case for that too. But it's not necessary to restrict the task to polynomials which are a product of linear factors and one irreducible factor, because it's not necessary to test irreducibility. On the assumption that this is a [tag:code-golf], I would expect everyone to use the Cauchy bound on the real roots.

Comment: A function which takes a string and returns a string is fine, although you might want to say "function, named block, or named verb" to cover some of the languages which are used a lot more on this site than in the real world.

Comment: Well you do not have to use the bounds, since all the roots have to divide the constant term.

Answer (score 1):

## Survival of the fittest [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

As [Chris Jester-Young](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-jester-young) suggested [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/having-an-idea-to-a-good-question-where-should-i-post-it-first/), i will propose my challenge here. At the moment, this is merely a draft but i want to ask for suggestions to this idea as early as possible.

For discussions, i suggest using the chatroom at [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15700/survival-of-the-fittest-discussion) specifically for this challenge.

My draft in its newest state plus all source code is hosted at [github](https://github.com/Kostronor/SOTF) where you can make pull requests with suggestions.

---

The post here consists of the rules my challenge will have. Look at the github to see a lengthy explanation of what i post here. Feedback of all kind is appreciated!

---

## Rules

**Board**

The challenge is held on a two dimensional board with x and y coordinates. 0|0 is on the left-top side and increases in y downwards and in x to the right. Every field on the board can only hold one object. Objects are all kind of things in the game, from resources to units and even buildings. Board corners are solid, so the board is surrounded by walls. Everything on the board is randomly distributed. The board size is determined by the number of players in the game.

**Actions**

Every AI acts as one faction of humans. These factions have their explicit name and can be recognized by all other factions. Each round, all factions are given the complete board state and they have to submit some actions. Actions will be executed based on the time stamp of submission. So a faster calculating AI has the benefit of moving first. Animals and NPCs will move after all actions from the AIs are executed. Then there is a new round.

**Game limits**

The game ends, when there is only one faction left. There can be a time limit, if is turns out to take ages... There will also be a time limit for each round. Taking more time than the limit means, your program will be cut off and the rest of your actions will be omitted. After 5 consecutive rounds hitting the time limit, an AI will be disqualified.

**Gameplay**

Each faction starts the game with four workers and a stockpile. They have to collect wood, stone and food to survive. Food is used up every round to fill the workers stomach. All three resources will be needed to construct buildings and advance in technology and in numbers. Workers are able to reproduce in housings. but they can also be converted to soldiers. Soldiers can not work nor reproduce, but excel in their fighting ability. With more advanced technology, workers can be converted to better soldiers. Soldiers can not be upgraded.

**Strategy**

There are numerous buildings available and the more advanced cost a huge amount of resources. Fighters can destroy buildings, while workers can conquer them. Buildings allow for things like reproductions, boosts on resource collection and overall attributes of each unit. Units get more experienced in things, while they are doing them. This experience is handed down to the next generation. Since there need to be two units, to get an offspring, a genetic algorithm will mix their abilities together. This can be better or worse. Your units can have offspring with units from other factions, but both units have to agree on the matter. The offspring randomly chooses between the two factions and stays there.

**Control**

The AI does not control its units directly. It only gives orders. There is no limit on how many orders an AI can give each turn but every unit can only have one active order at a time. Giving a second order overrides the first one. Units try to execute the orders that are given to them. They are doing this automatically and orders are carried to the next round, if they are not fully completed. While the AI hat full informations over the board, their units have not. Giving an attack order to a place the unit can't see, the unit will try to walk there and attack when in view of the target.

**Alliances**

There is a global chat that all AIs share and where all AIs can talk to while calculating actions. AIs can specify other AIs that they think are friendly. They can not attack these. If two AIs each think of each other as friendly, they from a bond. A chain of such bonds is called an alliance. Even if you do not consider them friendly, your alliances friends are not attackable for you. So forming an alliance with someone, who friends everyone means, you cannot attack anyone, but they can attack you, if they don't friend back. Each round you can alter your friends to your liking. There is no such thing as an alliance chat, so you have to use encryption to chat in secret. And remember, in the end, only one AI wins the game.

**Scoring**

Scoring is done in number of rounds survived. Perhaps there will be some more scoring factors included to make the game more interesting.

---

Please bear in mind, that i will edit this answer a lot the next time to reflect the changes in the challenge.

Comment: This is rather vague at the moment. What do you want feedback on?

Comment: I wanted to propose the idea of a challenge like this here first. I am at the moment thinking about the rules of the challenge. Any 'Hey, xyz would be cool!' or 'what if abc?' helps me. It will get less vague soon! Until then, every meta-feedback on the challenge is appreciated. Just speak out your mind.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have now written an outline of the rules, this challenge will have. Can you look over it and tell me, if something is unclear?

Comment: I suggest to add titles to each text-section you have. It is quite hard to read right now...

Comment: @Manu I have added some titles that seem to fit well. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Kostronor much better :) As Peter Taylor said, everything is rather vague. Try to specify rules, such as the time limit, actions and so on...

Comment: @Manu My intention for this project is to make something a bit more complex, that has many distinct strategies to win. I am writing on the controller at the moment, which helps me specify the rules in a more detailed manner. Until then, can you give me some feedback on the overall gameplay? Do you think, this could be interesting?

Comment: @Kostronor Sure it is interesting. I hope it doesn't get too complicated ;)

Comment: This sounds really interesting to me. However, especially due to the complexity, be prepared to get only a handful of submissions. So far the popular KotH's were popular because you could whip up a simple bot in a couple of minutes (which wouldn't have any chance of winning, but it's fun posting it anyway to get the ball rolling). If your game is sufficiently complex that even the most basic strategy takes half an hour and some debugging to implement, that will put a lot of people off (who might take this on them if there are already simpler submissions to be beaten).

Comment: Btw, I really like the idea of handling commands in the order they come in! :)

Comment: @m.buettner I thought, to lower the starting requirements, i will write some basic bots myself, where everyone can start. I think, the main focus should be on the strategy and not on the coding, so i will try and get some abstraction done, like the example bots from 'petri dish'. Yeah, the commands in order thing is something, that trades of better action against faster thinking. But it's a pain to implement it ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Empire wars

This is very close to Risk, but not quite. You command an empire, composed of armies, trying to take over the world.

#### The world

The world is a grid. For `n` competitors, the side length of the grid is `sqrt(n)*4` (casted to an integer). At the beginning, the world is part of the "neutral" empire. Each neutral army contains 200 soldiers. The neutral army only defends, it never attacks. Your starting army of your empire is randomly selected from the grid. Note that the world wraps around if you go off the edge.

#### Receiving soldiers

Every turn, you will be given `500 + 50t` soldiers to distribute, where `t` is the number of armies/territories you command. You can give any amount to any army, as long as you don't exceed `500 + 50t` in total.

You may then attack or transfer any number of soldiers to another location.

That means that, if you have enough soldiers, you can move soldiers from multiple different territories to multiple new territories.

#### Attack/Transfer

During your turn, you may move any number of soldiers from any of your armies to any of the squares bordering your army. You can move diagonally. One of two things will happen

1. You already control the square your army is moving to:
      Nothing special. The new square gets some more soldiers.
2. Another empire controls the square:
      The two armies will fight (see below). If your army wins, the surviving soldiers will inhabit the territory. Otherwise, any surviving soldiers will retreat back.

#### Battle

The order of battle is randomized every turn, because the empires who go first have a slight advantage or disadvantage (depends on the algorithm). For example, if I occupy a territory on my turn, but I go before another empire, then that empire could potentially attack my new territory.

Suppose `a` is the number of soldiers attacking and `d` is the number of soldiers defending. The defenders lose `a * 0.6` soldiers and the attackers lose `d * 0.7` soldiers. If the defenders have no soldiers remaining, the attacker's surviving soldiers inhabit the territory. For example, suppose the world looks like:

```
N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
N-200 N-200 A-500 N-200
N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
```

where `N-200` represents a neutral army with 200 soldiers and `A-500` represents an army of your empire. Suppose the following happens:

1. Your empire (`A`) decides to move 250 people north. First of all, north is not controlled by your empire, so a battle is started. `N-200` loses `250 * 0.6` soldiers and `A-500` loses `200 * 0.7` soldiers, with a result of `N-200 --> 50` and the 250 attacking soldiers will be reduced to 110. Since the territory wasn't conquered, the 110 survivors retreat. The world will now look like:

   ```
   N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
   N-200 N-200 N-50 N-200
   N-200 N-200 A-360 N-200
   N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
   ```
2. You now decide to move 180 people north. The same thing happens: `N-50` loses `108` soldiers and `A-360` loses `35` soldiers. Since `N-50` has been eliminated, the remaining `58` soldiers move into the new territory.

   ```
   N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
   N-200 N-200 A-58 N-200
   N-200 N-200 A-180 N-200
   N-200 N-200 N-200 N-200
   ```

Note that neutral territories never attack.

#### Example implementation:

The code should be in Java (thinking of extending it to other languages) and needs to extend the abstract class `Empire`.

```
// The code MUST be in the package "empire" and extend the class "Empire" from mainengine
package empire;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import mainengine.*;

public class TestEmpire1 extends Empire {
    // Occurs at the beginning of the turn
    // You get 500 + 50t soldiers to deploy
    @Override
    public void deploy(ArmyDeployer toDeploy) {
        // Get all of my armies
        List<Army> armies = getArmies();
        // Distribute my new armies to each army evenly
        int perArmy = toDeploy.armiesLeft() / armies.size();
        for (Army a : armies) {
            a.addPower(toDeploy, perArmy);
        }
    }

    // You can move your armies as well
    @Override
    public void move() throws IOException {
        // Get the world
        World world = World.world;
        // Get the map of the world
        // Note that you can only see the areas adjacent to your armies
        // All other locations appear as "null"
        Army[][] map = getMap();
        for (Army a : getArmies()) {
            // Find the least guarded territory
            Move bestMove = null;
            int leastDefended = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Move move : Move.values()) {
                int newX = world.wrapPosition(move.getXOffset() + a.getPoint().x),
                    newY = world.wrapPosition(move.getYOffset() + a.getPoint().y);
                if (map[newY][newX] != null && map[newY][newX].getStrength() <= leastDefended) {
                    leastDefended = map[newY][newX].getStrength();
                    bestMove = move;
                }
            }
            // Attack with half of our strength
            a.move(bestMove, a.getStrength() / 2);
        }
    }

}
```

See github for the code that will be executing it: https://github.com/prakol16/EmpireWars/tree/master/EmpireWars/src

The "number of points" that an empire receives is how many territories it controls after one run (about 50, subject to change, or so turns). The program will be run 10 times and the empire with the most total points wins.

In addition, the program creates an html file `record.html` which contains a record of every turn.

Comment: Sounds interesting! :) A few comments: 1. I don't think this is very close to Risk. I'd say "inspired by Risk" is as close as it gets, because I suspect the battle system to play out vastly differently (for instance, attackers are always at a disadvantage here). 2. Up until your example it's not clear that neutral territories *are* occupied by some army, and that this neutral empire starts with 200 soldiers on each cell. 3. Since this caused some confusion recently, I'd remove "the world is round" (and only mention that it wraps around), because it implies that the world is spherical... [ctd.]

Comment: in which case north/south *wouldn't* wrap around. A map which wraps on both edges is in fact in the shape of a torus, but mentioning that would probably confuse some other people, so I'd say only state that both edges wrap around and nothing else. 4. How many are "many rounds" (after which the game ends)? 5. You might want to think about providing a wrapper implementation of `Empire` which calls a separate process, in order to allow submissions in other languages. [Like Rusher did here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/good-versus-evil). 6. Can I attack and transfer... [ctd.]

Comment: units from multiple territories into multiple territories within a single round? Or do I have to stick to one transfer or one (repeated) attack? 7. I suppose the order of players will be randomised? I also expect a fair share of submissions to be probabilistic. In that case deciding the overall winner based on a single run might not be fair (unless the winner is always the same submission anyway). Are you prepared to run multiple simulations if that happens (such that the winner is submission that wins the largest number of individual simulations)?

Comment: @m.buettner Ok, updated some stuff. For #4, 7: I'm not sure how many yet, but it should be enough that luck doesn't affect the empire that much. For #6: Yes, you can send different commands to multiple armies in different locations. Just note that if you occupy a new territory, it won't be available for you to command until the next turn. #7. Yes, the order is randomized every turn, because if I occupy a territory, even though I can't command it immediately, another empire could still attack me immediateley.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying. I don't like the idea of sending your orders before everyone makes their turn. You'd have *no* idea what would happen to the territories you're attacking before you're actually invading there. 8. How many soldiers do I have to leave behind when attacking/transferring?

Comment: @m.buettner You could potentially leave none when attacking/transferring. That would leave the territory completely undefended though. As for sending your orders before everyone makes their turn: if it isn't done this way, then the people who go first have a huge disadvantage because they don't know anything about who's attacking the territory, while the ones who go last have lots of information. Your orders should be based on what's currently there (what happened in the previous turn)

Comment: If you buffer the orders, those going at the end will have a huge disadvantage because they have no idea what the map will look like when their order is actually carried out, whether there's no uncertainty at all for those going first. I think this difference is *much* more unfair than the first player having to make a decision before everyone else. 9. Do you get your soldiers when it's your turn or does everyone get their soldiers at the same time once *everyone*'s moves have been completed?

Comment: @m.buettner I see your point. I don't think I'll buffer the orders then (it makes more sense not to now that I think about it). 9. Everyone gets soldiers at the same time.

Comment: You could look at the board game Diplomacy for some ideas about how to handle simultaneous resolution of everyone's orders. (I confess that I don't know offhand whether it's a good system, but I do know that it's *a* system).

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly done now, just need someone to double check that everything makes sense

## Generate Lightning Forks in a 3D Grid

## Objective:

**Overview:**
Write a program, that given the two inputs **number of rays** and **ray length**, will produce a procedurally random array of connected points, containing the **ray number**, **number in sequence** and **coordinates** of each point.

**Details:**
The lightning is in the form of **rays**, which are determined by points stored as **coordinates in a grid**.
The initial point (0,0,0), is the cloud, where the lightning is first generated. The first ray starts here and travels out in a random direction, and will continue moving in random directions (each point has an equal chance of any direction, not influenced by the previous point), and will terminate once it reaches the ray length limit or cannot go any further (if it fails enough new direction retries when intersecting with another point). This will leave a single path between the origin and the end point.
However, lighting doesn't stay as one single ray and will fork, so while all other rays should be generated in a similar way, their origin should be randomly chosen from any of the already generated points, and the sequence then continues from this point.

The **Ray Number** is simply which ray iteration the code is on. Each ray is it's own individual path. The origin point of the ray will have the same coordinates as the point it branches off from.
The **Number In Sequence** is how many points away from the cloud (or how far into the generation) it is. If lightning forks at point 50, both separate paths will start at 51. While this is not currently used for anything aside from checking the code is working correctly, it would allow for future improvements such as animation (see gif at bottom for an example).
**Coordinates** are the 3D points the ray passes through. They should be stored as integers.

**Simple 2D Diagram:**
Here is an example output *during generation* after 24 points have been calculated.
The numbers written in black are the numbers in sequence, and as you can see when the 2nd ray (blue) branches out, it continues from 10. The red line is an example of when it would try intersect with existing points and get stuck. This shows the cloud as it's own ray, you are free however to do this differently.
[image: diagram]

## Rules:

- Can be written in any code (without extra plugins), although I can't guarantee anything but PHP and Python will be tested, unless someone else with access to a lot more languages helps out.
- Randomness must be seed based, so *if* you were to define a seed (not needed), it would produce the same result.
- A point can move in any **one** of the 3 dimensions - meaning it can go up, down, left, right, forwards, or backwards (x,y,z,-x,-y,-z) from the previous point, but not diagonally.
- No two points can have the same coordinates.
- The one exception of this rule is that each ray must start with the same coordinate of where it branches out (for the purpose of connecting everything together).
- If an intersection is detected, at least 3 retries must be done to find new direction, then it may be terminated. The retries must be for each point, so having 1 retry on 3 different points shouldn't terminate the ray.
- No multithreading allowed.
- The code should output the final number of points generated and time taken.
- The program should be timed to when the array of points is complete. Anything after this (such as for the bonus points) is fine and won't impact on the execution time.

## Scoring:

- Generate 100 rays with a maximum length of 200. If your code is super efficient and you want to show off, you're welcome to post the times for more complex results.
- Most efficient code wins, based on the execution time. Someone will test multiple submissions and take an average from at least 4 generations to make it more fair.

**Important:** So I can easily check your code works as it should, I wrote something that will display the rays in a 3D program.
You'll need to generate 30 rays with a length of 15, in **2D** (easy to switch - where it randomly chooses from from 6 directions, change this to 4), and copy it to pastebin. Format it like I have done here, and keep it limited to square brackets, commas, and integers: http://pastebin.com/8XHtv4is

**Bonus Points:**

- Given any two random points, there is one and only path between them both. If you can code something that would be able to calculate a path between these two random points and store it in a new array with the same structure, you get 15% off the execution time.
- Instead of limited to 3 dimensions, code it for `n` dimensions, as more than 3 dimensions should work, despite being a little hard to visualise. If you manage you can knock 10% from the execution time.
- As not everyone will be able to do it, this is only worth 5%, but you get it, if you code a way to visually draw the rays (2D is allowed, any method is allowed, but it must be able to run at the end of the code, as opposed to copying the list into a graphing program).

## Tips:

- Start working with a 2D grid for easier debugging.
- Use small ray length and ray amount values until properly optimised.
- While intersections are fairly easy to see, diagonals are not, running the code with a single short ray to print the output can be useful.

## Example code:

Generation Time for 100x200: 75-85 seconds

```
length=15
forks=30
import time
import random as rd
startTime=time.time()
def getDirection(num):
    if(num==1):
        direction=[1,0,0]
    if(num==2):
        direction=[-1,0,0]
    if(num==3):
        direction=[0,1,0]
    if(num==4):
        direction=[0,-1,0]
    if(num==5):
        direction=[0,0,1]
    if(num==6):
        direction=[0,0,-1]
    return direction
listOfPoints = [[0,[0,0,0],0]]
for i in range(forks):
    randomPoint = listOfPoints[rd.randint(0,len(listOfPoints)-1)]
    start = randomPoint[0]
    newLocation = randomPoint[1]
    listOfPoints.append([randomPoint[0],randomPoint[1],i+1])
    j=0
    j2=0
    while j in range(length):
        j+=1
        oldLocation = newLocation
        k = 0
        while True:
            invalid = 0
            newDirection = getDirection(rd.randint(1,6))
            newLocation = [oldLocation[0]+newDirection[0],oldLocation[1]+newDirection[1],oldLocation[2]+newDirection[2]]
            for n in range(len(listOfPoints)):
                location = listOfPoints[n][1]
                if location==newLocation:
                    invalid = 1
                    newLocation = oldLocation
            if invalid==0 or k>4:
                break
            k+=1
        if invalid == 0:
            listOfPoints.append([j2+start+1,newLocation,i+1])
            j2+=1

print "Time: "+str(round(time.time()-startTime,2))+" seconds"
print "Generated/Maximum points: "+str(len(listOfPoints))+"/"+str(length*forks)+"("+str(round(len(listOfPoints)/float(length*forks),3))+"%)"
```

## Visualised Output:

(From a more advanced version I did before, I was aiming to make a flower)
[image: diagram]

Comment: You seem to be using the word "fork" to mean two different things: a single line of points, and a bifurcation where one line becomes two. Perhaps you could use "ray" for the first, since it's conceptualised as a lightning simulator. You also seem to use "point" to mean "point in an integer lattice", but I don't think you actually state anywhere that you're working solely in integers.

Comment: Is the cloud at the origin (0,0,0)? Does the first ray travel in a random direction, or always in the same direction? When the first bifurcation is created by picking a random point on the first ray, does the second ray travel in a random direction or always in the same direction? If in a random direction, what happens if the direction selected is parallel with the first ray?

Comment: The explanation of bifurcation says that "*However, lightning doesn't stay as one straight line, so for the second fork...*" This strongly implies that each ray is a straight line. But the 2D diagram shows rays changing direction a lot. What is the correct generation process for a single ray? For the "cannot go any further" termination process to kick in, does it have to be unable to go in any direction at all, or just to pick a random direction which is blocked? (This is partially explained further down in the rules, but it would be convenient to group the explanation in one place).

Comment: What is the point of the unique ID? Each tuple would already appear to have at least one primary key: the (fork number, number in sequence) pair. The later rules seem to make it clear that the coordinates are also a primary key.

Separately, what are the parameters of the simple 2D diagram? In particular, what is the fork length? The red line seems to imply a lower bound of 13, but the blue line isn't that long.

Comment: You can pretty much guarantee that someone will be able to test most obscure languages posted here. See also [this meta thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1213/194).

Up, down, left, right, forwards, and backwards are 6 *directions*, not 6 *dimensions*. It sounds like you actually want 3 dimensions.

There's no point posting obfuscated example code. In general, it's better to post a reference implementation as an answer to avoid clutter.

The 2D visualised output is unhelpful. I would remove it to avoid confusing people. The hand-drawn 2D image is a lot more useful.

Comment: The bottleneck for many implementations could well be the I/O, so you should explain how you will take that into account when measuring performance. On the bonuses: Calculating the path between two items in a tree should be pretty simple: you track back from both until you find a common ancestor. But even though it's simple, you don't say how much of a bonus it gives. The other bonus confuses matters slightly when it says that it "should technically work for infinite dimensions": actually, it can't, because there's no fair probability distribution over an infinite set.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll reword the question and set it to generating lightning forks, gives it a better title. As to the potential infinite dimensions, how would you reword it? I could manually code in 100 dimensions if I wanted to spend 20 minutes doing it, I'm just suggesting someone codes the option where it'll do it automatically.

Comment: Oh also, as to the bottleneck you mentioned, that's the main efficiency problem, I'm curious if anyone can find a method that doesn't involve reading the entire list every time a new point is added

Comment: Hey, just updated it again, do things make a lot more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

## Making a dichotomous key

A [dichotomous key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-access_key), also known as a single-access key is often used to identify plants/animals. Your task is, given a set of data, write the shortest program that outputs the shortest (in steps) possible dichotomous key. If there are multiple solutions, the program may print either one.

**Input**

Input will be received by `stdin`, or in cases where that doesn't exist (e.g. Client-side javascript) you can take input from `prompt` or something similar.

The input will be a list of items followed by characteristics: The format of the definition of an item will be

```
item[delimiter1]characteristic1[delimiter2]characteristic2[delimiter2]characteristic3
```

Your program may choose the delimiters. In this example, I will use `:` as delimiter one, and `,` as delimeter 2. Between each item definition is `delimiter3`, which will be `\n` in this example (but you can make it anything that isn't `delimiter1` or `delimiter2`). Note that none of the delimeters can be `[a-zA-Z]` letters.

Characteristics and items are composed of a series of `[a-zA-Z]` characters.

Example input:

```
quadrilateral:fourSides
trapezoid:fourSides,onePairParallel
parallelogram:fourSides,twoPairsParallel,oppositeSidesEqual
rectangle:fourSides,twoPairsParallel,fourRightAngles,oppositeSidesEqual
rhombus:fourSides,twoPairsParallel,oppositeSidesEqual,allSidesEqual
square:fourSides,twoPairsParallel,oppositeSidesEqual,allSidesEqual,fourRightAngles
```

**Output**

Output should be written to `stdout`, or `alert` or something similar where it doesn't exist.

You must output a characteristic followed by delimiter one, followed by two integers separated by delimiter two. The first is the step to go to if the item contains the characteristic, and the second is the step to go to if the item doesn't contain the characteristic. Note that the 1st step is considered `0`. Alternatively, instead of an integer, you could have an item.

Example output:

```
twoPairsParallel:2,1
onePairParallel:trapezoid,quadrilateral
allSidesEqual:3,4
fourRightAngles:square,rhombus
fourRightAngles:rectangle,parallelogram
```

This is code-golf so shortest code wins.

Comment: The example output looks wrong to me. Shouldn't the first line be `twoPairsParallel:2,1`? Also, since the transformation doesn't inherently use any biology at all and since you use shapes, it would be clearer to talk in terms of "*classes*" or "*taxons*" rather than "*organisms*". It's also good to be explicit about I/O assumptions; since you talk about a program and string delimiters between items in a list, I would guess that you want a full program which takes input from stdin and writes output to stdout. State that.

Answer (score 1):

## XKCD: (Battle of the) Hats

http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/hats.png

Enough background, get into the game

A [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge.

You all started at a point. At the count on 3, you decides to wear yourself 1 black hat, 2 black hats or 1 white hat.

Here's what happened: (If you find this description confusing, you can look at the table below, credit to Peter Taylor)

---

If you use 1 black hat ->

-> If your opponent also uses 1 black hat or white hat, your opponent moves backward 1 step.

-> If your opponent uses 2 black hats, you have 50% chance making your opponent moves 2 steps backward. Else your opponent does nothing.

---

If you use 2 black hats ->

-> If your opponent doesn't use white hat, your move is considered successful 2 black hats attempt. Your opponent moves backward x+3 steps, where x is # of your previous successful 2 black hats attempt.

-> Else: Your attack gives no effect.

---

If you use white hat ->

-> If your opponent use 2 black hat, you're considered making successful white hat attempt. Your opponent moves backward y+3 steps, where y is # of your previous successful white hat attempt.

-> Else: You're considered making a failed white hat attempt. **You** move backward z+3 steps, where z is # of your previous **failed** white hat attempt.

---

The game ends when somebody moves 20 step backward or 10 rounds played.

If one person moves 20 or more steps backward while one doesn't, then the one who not is declared the winner.

If both moves 20 or more steps backward in the same round or no one moves 20 or more steps backward in 10 rounds, no one win.

Your bot will play 5 tournaments. In each tournament, you face each enemy once. The player who score most win in those 5 tournaments accumulated, is declared the champion

### Communication Protocol

Your bot will get this from STDIN:

```
id round step0 step1 move0 move 1
```

Where `id` is your player id, can be 0 or 1; `round` means current round (match starts at Round 1); `step0` and `step1` means how many step has player 0 and player 1 has taken; `move0` and `move1` is the move taken by player 0 and player 1.

In first round, move 0 and move 1 will be empty. In next round, it will the move as this

```
12w21
```

This means one player use 1 black hat; 2 black hats;  white hat; 2 black hats; 1 black hat, respectively.

Your bot gives me output from your STDOUT as `1` if your bot want to wear 1 black hat, `2` if your bot want to wear 2 black hats, `w` if your bot want to wear white hat.

PS: Do aware that I use small-case "w"

---

Table:

```
                +--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
                |                    |     P0 action      |                     |
                |         1          |         2          |          w          |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|             1 | P0 back 1          | P0 back 0 or 2     | P0 back z0+4; z0++  |
|               | P1 back 1          | P1 back x0+3; x0++ | .                   |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| P1 action   2 | P0 back x1+3; x1++ | P0 back x1+3; x1++ | .                   |
|               | P1 back 0 or 2     | P1 back x0+3; x0++ | P1 back y0+3; y0++  |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|             w | .                  | P0 back y1+3; y1++ | P0 back z0+3; z0++  |
|               | P1 back z1+4; z1++ | .                  | P1 back z1+3; z1++  |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: 1. The scoring table would almost certainly be easier to read in a table. 2. Could you be more precise in the definition of `x`, `y`, `z`? Whose previous moves are counted, and what counts as "successful"? 3. In the "You move z+3 steps", is that forwards or backwards? 4. Is it intended that the bots should not know what `x`, `y`, `z` are? 5. It makes more sense for the controller (of which there is one) to handle the naming issue and let each bot (maybe a dozen) handle the simple case of always being player 0.

Comment: You can figure `x` `y` `z` from history move. For the scoring table, I cant figure out how to make this without using image (trying to make this as html as possible), I shall rewrite the 2 black hats and white hats.

Comment: I agree that a table that is not an image would be better, but until you find a way to make that work, please could you include an image of a table?

Comment: The table won't fit or render correctly in a comment, so I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have credited you.

Answer (score 1):

## Confused Automatons [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### [work in progress]

This is a 1v1 (or not? could be more) king-of-the-hill, where you and your opponent both issue commands to the same, perpetually confused, gladiators and try to survive.

Toroidal arena with N gladiators. They understand the following simple commands:

- `M`ove one of 8 directions or
- `H`old

plus one of:

- `S`hoot target. Range of 5. Can’t shoot the following turn.
- `D`odge (no target required)
- `N`othing

On each turn you may issue one command (`[M/H]+[S/D/N]`) to *each* gladiator. All gladiators will execute the commands from *both* players each turn. Movement happens first. If a gladiator is given two shoot commands, they will shoot twice that turn; two dodge commands and they will dodge twice. One dodge will avoid one shot. A gladiator can't shoot himself. Movement in opposite directions will cancel; movement in the same direction means moving a distance of two. If there is both an [H] command and an [M] command for the same gladiator, the [H] will be ignored.

One of the gladiators is your commander. You lose when your commander dies. Your commander ignores commands from your opponent. You don’t know which gladiator is your opponent’s commander.

### Input

TBD

### Output

TBD

### Scoring

TBD

Comment: I am just as confused as the automoton.  Won't you easily be able to figure out which gladiator is the commander by seeing who ingored the command?

Answer (score 1):

## Code Bots ϕ

This is a challenge based on the popular Code Bots ("What's wrong with public variables?") [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36978/whats-wrong-with-public-variables).

I made a few observations during the development of the original Code Bots:

1. I had a literal ton of ideas and wouldn't stop harassing Nathan Merrill about them.
2. Nathan Merrill already claimed Code Bots 2.

The solution is obvious: make my own challenge.  So, that is exactly what I intend to do.

**Note: I am working on various ways to distinguish the two challenges.**

### Variables

Note: I have changed the names of some variables to make them more "intuitive."

The variables `A` and `B` each store an integer 0-23.

The variable `C` (for Control) stores an integer 0-23 and is incremented at the end of every turn.  It indicates which line of the program is to be executed.

The variable `D` (for Direction) stores and integer 0-23, which determines the current direction of the bot.  The direction is determined by `{north east south west}[[D % 4]]`.

The variable `E` (for Entropy) is overwritten by a random integer at the end of each turn, but only if your bot uses it that turn.

The variable `F` (for Feeling) provides a sense of touch.  This allows you to detect when a bot is next to you.  The value equals the number of adjacent bots.  For example, `F` equals `4` when you are completely surrounded on all four sides (and thus out of luck).

The variable `G` (for aGe) provides a timer.  The value is incremented after the end of every turn, mod 24.  This allows an easy way to do `for`-like loops.

### Instructions

Each line contains a single command, and each command takes a variety of arguments.

`Flag` : This represents your flag.  Your goal is to smear your flag across the known universe.  Each flag line has a hidden identifier denoting the owner.  These lines do nothing upon execution.

`Move` : This moves the bot 1 unit forward in the direction that it is facing.

`Copy [expr|line] [var|line]` : This copies one expression to another. Both expressions must be of the same type.  You can copy a line to another line or copy the value of one variable to another. Copying to yourself has a new advantage in that, instead of making an immediate change, the change is made just prior to the start of your next turn.

`Copy2 [expr|line] [var|line]` : This is a new version of copy, but instead of performing the action immediately after your turn, it performs the action immediately before your next turn.  *[todo: find a better name for it. Maybe "DelayCopy"]*

`If [cond] [line] [line]` : This is an `If` statement, one of the most important statements.  If the conditional evaluates to true, then the first of the two lines is executed immediately afterwards (on the same turn).  If the conditional is false, then the second line is executed immediately afterwards.  In order to prevent infinite loops of various kinds, a bot is not allowed to execute the same line twice in a single turn.

`Jump [expr] [cond]` : This is a new instruction designed to help speed up bots. Given a number `N`, it immediately sets the value of `C` to `N` and then executes `#N` on the same turn.  The condition is optional, but if present it will determine whether or not the Jump command is executed or not.

`Block [var|line]` : This blocks a certain variable or line.  Each variable or line can be blocked once, and this block prevents one modification attempt of that variable/line.  If an opponent (or yourself) attempts to modify that variable, then the variable is merely unblocked rather than modified.

### Arguments

There are four types of arguments, `var`, `line`, `expr`, and `cond`.  Here are their relationships:

```
 var = *[var] | A | B | C | D | E
expr = [var] | [expr][op][expr] | [literal number]
 op = + | - | %
line = *[line] | #[expr]
cond = [expr] | [line] | [expr]=[expr] | [expr]==[expr] | [line]=[line] | [line]==[line]
```

There are three types of operators which can be used in expressions: Addition `+`, Subtraction `-`, and Modulo `%`. The modulo operator has highest preference (left to right), with addition/subtraction being applied afterwards.

There are several different kinds of conditionals.

1. `If [expr]` usually returns true if the value of the expression is non-zero.  There are several special cases. `If D` returns true if there is a bot directly in front of you.  `If E` returns true if `E` is odd.  (Note: add more special cases)
2. `If [line]` returns true if the line contains a flag.
3. `If [expr]=[expr]` returns true if the two expressions are equal mod 4.
4. `If [line]=[line]` returns true if the two lines are the same type (same command).
5. `If [expr]==[expr]` returns true if both expressions are equal mod 24.
6. `If [line]==[line]` returns true if the two lines are exactly equal (such as both flags having the same owner).

### The Turn Structure

```
(Initially, all variables are 0 except for E)
[command execution starts]
The command at line #C is executed.
If there is a chain of logic, it is followed until it stops or a line is visited twice.
[updates]
The effect of a Copy statement is applied, if any.
C is incremented
If needed, E is randomized.
(other bot's turns here)
F is updated
The effect of a Copy2 statement is applied, if any.
[next command execution]
```

### Line Labels

To increase the ease of writing bots, there will be new things called line labels, which look like this `word:` and can be placed at the start of a line.  Later in the code, you can reference the line label like this `:word`.  (Note:  The exact formatting is up for discussion).

During preprocessing, the controller will replace all instances of `:word` with the number of the line labeled `word:`.  If the `:word` label is the only thing on the line (no command) then the entire line will be copied into that blank line.  Here is an example:

```
main: If D #:move #:attack
:main
:main
Jump :main
move: Move
attack: Copy #:flag *#*C
```

### Other usability features

The language will be completely case-insensitive.  Comments will take the form of `//comment`.

### The Arena

There will be 50 bots of each type entered into an arena.  Initially, all of the bots will be evenly spaced on a grid and facing north.

```
....@.......@.......
.......@.......@....
..@.......@.......@.
.....@.......@......
@.......@.......@...
...@.......@.......@
......@.......@.....
.@.......@.......@..
```

Note: I believe this to be an improvement because the bots are not directly lined up with each other.  In Code Bots 1, a bot could `Move` on its first turn and end up right behind another bot.  In this grid, a bot has a much smaller chance of

### A complicated example bot

Each bot can contain up to 24 lines, and each line contains an instruction.  If there are any blank lines (after substitution with line labels), then those lines are filled by Flags.

```
main: If D #:attackloop #:move        //attack if an opponent 
:main                             //automatically filled in with the same line
loop: jump :main                  //executes line 0 again and sets C to 0
move: if T #:run #:turn           //always move (never rotate) when being attacked
run: Move
turn: If E #:run #:turn2          //randomly pick move or rotate
turn2: Copy2 D+1 D
attackloop: jump :attack
attack: Copy #:freeze *#*C         //freeze the opponent
plant: Copy #C+6 *#E              //plant your flag
:plant
:plant
:plant
Jump :loop                        //return to main loop
freeze: Copy2 C-1 C             //this creates an endless loop when executed
```

After preprocessing, the above bot turns into the bot below.  You can also simply submit the bot below without using any line labels if you'd like.

```
If D #8 #3
If D #8 #3
Jump 0
If T #4 #5
Move
If E #4 #6 
Copy2 D+1 D
Jump 9
Copy #14 *#*C
Copy #C+6 *#E
Copy #C+6 *#E
Copy #C+6 *#E
Copy #C+6 *#E
Jump 2
Copy2 C-1 C
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
Flag
```

### Short, Useful Code Snippets

```
Block #G
Jump 0 G   //block all the lines in 24 moves
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unicode Case Mapping [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Challenge:

Given a string as input, print it in both lowercase and uppercase.

The string will be valid UTF-8, and your output should be as well. Characters without lowercase or uppercase mappings should be printed unmodified. Invalid, un-assigned, and private-use characters need not be handled.

Uppercasing and lowercasing should be doing according to Unicode 7.0 "simple" case mapping rules.

#### Rules:

This is code-golf, shortest program wins. Your program shouldn't use any external data files or access anything from the internet; all of the information it needs should be contained within the code itself.

You may not use your language's built-in case-mapping functions, built-in copies of the Unicode Character Databse, or libraries such as ICU. For example, in Perl the `lc` and `uc` functions as well as `Unicode::UCD` are prohibited.

Since this challenge is about Unicode I will throw in a small scoring twist: if your program is valid Unicode text (in whatever encoding your language prefers, probably UTF-8) you may score it at a rate of one point per character (regardless of how many bytes those characters take up). If it contains binary data then it must be scored at one point per byte. I will clarify what constitutes "binary data" if I have to.

#### Bonus:

Support "full" Unicode case mapping. The difference between "full" and "simple" mapping is that in "simple" mapping every codepoint maps to a single codepoint, while in full mapping a codepoint may map to multiple codepoints. For example, the uppercase of the character "ﬀ" (U+FB00) is "FF" (U+0046 U+0046). Assume that all "conditions" are false (that is, any rule with a non-empty `condition_list` should be ignored).

*Question: offer a point bonus for this? Recognize a separate winner among people that manage it? Drop it entirely?*

#### Resources:

- [Unicode Standard Annex #44: Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-14.html) — documentation for the UCD files.
- [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) — Unicode character properties, including simple lowercase/uppercase/titlecase mappings.
- [SpecialCasing.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt) — Special-case rules for casing: contains full mappings.

Comment: Created at the suggestion of @guifa after [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36802/concise-case-changing-code) challenge.

Comment: Interesting and to the best of my memory not a dupe. It's going to need a good set of test cases, and they may need to be provided in base64 or hexdump format.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have no problem supplying those :)

Comment: Do empty characters like '' count towards the score?

Answer (score 1):

### King of the server - virus wars

- There is a virtual machine with Linux running various services (SSH server, Apache (with SSL), FTP server, rsync server, etc);
- There is tool which checks that the server is running (periodically accessing all its services - trying to view the page from Apache, download a file from FTP server, etc.) and analysing responses for special ID codes;
- There are submissions that are started on the server as root and should "inject" some ID code (individual per solution) in as much as possible places while inhibiting competitors;
- Each solution should try to attain the following goals:
- - Make the server and it's services mention the ID code in maximum number of places with maximum reliability;
- - Avoid stopping the server or breaking any of the services, avoid breaking reboots;
- - Inhibiting competiting solutions (if any) while allowing them to post their ID code at least once;

The virtual machine gets booted, the solutions gets started there, then the script accesses the server from virtual network to check SSH/FTP/HTTP/... still running. The script also looks at the reply and counts any ID codes that appears in the replies. It happens multiple times. The serve gets rebooted N times.

Not all solutions gets planted on the server each time, just some random subset.

A solutions scheduled for the given round receive negative penalty points if:

1. The server crashed (stopped replying on requests from the virtual network);
2. Some service on the server crashed (i.e. SSH still works, but HTTP is down);
3. A competing solution have failed to provide it's ID code even once;

If your solution crashes something or fails to provice the code even once even if run alone (without competitors) - it gets disqualified.

The solutions may use variety of methods to complete the goals:

1. Just changing configuration in `/etc`;
2. Patching system libraries to inject the ID code and/or supress other solutions;
3. Carrying "clean" copy of libraries to avoid point "2.";
4. Loading kernel modules;
5. Extracting competing ID code and manually providing it exactly once (to avoid the "spawn camping" early-kill  penalty);
6. Loading security modules to make `root` less omnipotent;
7. Overriding a boot loader, making the server boot nonstandardly...

The virtual machine image will be available from the beginning.

Questions:

1. Is the idea worth thinking and fits PPCG enough?
2. Shall all solutions be public from the beginning, or there can be hidden solutions (to prevent easy directed attacks)?
3. Shall binary-only submissions be allowed?

Comment: I'm not especially comfortable with this as a concept: it risks crossing the line into writing actual malware. But if you do go ahead with it, it has some other problems which need fixing. Most pressingly, unless the subsets run are fair, it penalises people for ending up in the same run as a bad bot. And that's without taking into account "*If your solution crashes something... it gets disqualified*". How are you going to attribute the blame when a combination of changes from different bots breaks things? As for binary-only submissions: you'd be foolhardy to run them.

Comment: `As for binary-only submissions: you'd be foolhardy to run them.` -> What's the problem? They are expected to be run in a fortified secured environment. Binary-only (or source + binary modified by hand) can be useful to dodge other bots.

Comment: `How are you going to attribute the blame when a combination of changes from different bots breaks things` -> The offending bot will get the most penalty (as it probably breaks something every time), and others only sporadically. Subset choice is random.

Comment: `crossing the line into writing actual malware` -> 1. It is inspired by how malware works; 2. Finding vulnerabilities is not a priority, as all solutions start as root from the beginning; 3. I haven't seen any anti-malware clauses in FAQ; 4. Bots do "distribute" only by mentioning some hash, not the actual code, client programs (FTP client, browser, etc) are out of scope.

Comment: Your points 1, 2 and 4 are relevant, but for point 3 I would point out that the FAQs and guidelines of PPCG and SE in general are not the only factors people base their votes on. Even if a question doesn't technically break any rules, it can be downvoted for being unethical, according to the various ethical positions of the voters. Hopefully enough people will share their ethical views here in the sandbox that you can stay the right side of their various lines.

Comment: You also need to bear in mind that just because you take steps to make sure a question doesn't result in usable malware doesn't stop the question giving the *impression* of being about creating malware. Just that potential impression is enough to make some people wary of allowing the question on the site - understandably as it may affect the perception of the site as a whole. Your question has the potential for a very interesting contest but you will have more work to do with this question than your average question due to having to tread carefully.

Comment: If you're asking for code which looks like malware, are you 100% certain that you (and everyone else who might want to test it) can tell it apart from *real* malware? If it's non-obfuscated source you can probably be moderately confident, but if you're allowing binary submissions then I stand by the word *foolhardy*. As to "*the offending bot will get the most penalty*", you haven't understood that question. I could rephrase it as "How do you decide *which one* is the offending bot?"

Comment: @PeterTaylor, The system should not peep into what actually happens on the server and can only observe crashed vs not crashed. Therefore the only viable option for penalties is to penalize everything, but let the statistics route the most of penalty points to the actual offender. Crashing services is not absolutely prohibited, it just attracts penalty points. But you can't use this tool against somebody else bot, unless it's many on one. The penalty points vs crash probability can be non-linear.

Comment: @PeterTaylor is right about the binary submissions. Reasonably readable code, though, would make this fun. </2cents>

Answer (score 1):

## [Dots and Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes)

The goal is writing a function in [language], that accepts the grid and outputs what dots it wants to connect next.
This is a King of the Hill challenge.

### How the game works

The (square) field has 6x6 dots. The two players are conenct one after another each time two neighbour dots (vertically or horizontally). If one player closed a square (1x1) in his last step, this square counts as his. The game is finished as soon there are no more dots to connect.

### Scoring

Each program will be playing against each other program.

The score is the total number of conquered number of boxes.

### Open Questions

- How can we encode the grid in an easy way as 2D(?) array?
- How should the function endcode which dots to connect?
- What language / environment would you suggest for doing so? (It would be easiest if there was only one language. I'd say Python or JavaScript.)
- Is it better to count the total of the captured squares or only the number of won matches?

Comment: [relevant](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/30313/8478)

Comment: What do you mean by "quadratic"?  I think this is a great idea however if you write some nice controller code. The easiest thing is to get the answers to read and write standard input/output I think that way answers can be in any language people want. Your code should verify they make a valid move however and just call the answer code with the new setup.

Comment: I mean 'square' sorry=) Since I am not THAT good at programming I thougth it would be best doing it in just one (popular and easy to use) language, so I could just copy/paste the code. The requirements for the controller code are: validation of moves, keeping track of the scores (and running all the games) something missing? What do you think about the other Question Another idea I just had was letting ALL the bots play together on one huge arena.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Squares (or Dots and Boxes as you call it) in four dimensional space. The winner is the person with the most whole tesseracts.

Comment: Ew. I do not think that I can wrap my head around that=) (I am not even sure whether the game would really work this way) but thanks for the input! Do you have an idea how to encode it in a 2d array?

Comment: This question needs a volunteer to rewrite it I think. It's a great idea but needs some effort from someone generous with their time.

Comment: What would you *change* / why would you rewrite it?

Comment: It needs a controller that calls people's code. Their code should take either a move or position as input and return a move. The controller should check this is valid and pass it to the other competitor. This allows people to write their answers in any language they like,

Comment: Of course but thats on the one hand what we've already discussed. And it makes no sence programming it as long as it is still unsure wheter it will make it out of the sandbox at all.

Comment: I think it won't make it out without a controller. Maybe someone will be kind enough to write one for you.

Comment: You could have a 2d array of `x by y` with each element representing the lines between each dot. You could then have populate the array with `N` as *unowned* and then have `A` if the line has been drawn by player A and `B` if a line has been drawn by player B. Then, you have another `x by y` 2d array with ownership of each box.

Comment: You could store the grid as a 2D array of the top-left corners. Each point has two lines that go right and down. For the bottom and right sides of the map, there is only one line (unless you want to make a toroidal map)

Comment: @Quincunx thanks, thats a good idea!

Comment: @flawr That's what I did to build my own dots and boxes controller for a KotH that I'm no longer going to host (I don't have time anymore)

Answer (score 1):

## Chad

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

[Chad](http://www.chessvariants.org/ms.dir/chad.html) is a variant of chess. It is played on an uncheckered board measuring twelve by twelve squares. Squares are denoted using standard chess notation, so `a12` is the top left corner and `l1` is the bottom right corner. The opening position of Chad looks like this:

[image: Opening Position of Chad]
*Above: Chad gameboard and opening position.*

The 3x3 area that the kings start in is called the *castle*. The twelve shaded squares around each castle is called the *wall*. Here are how the pieces interact with each other and the wall:

- The King can move and capture like a King but also as a Knight. However, he is confined to his 3x3 castle.
- The Rook moves like a Rook in chess, unimpeded by walls or castles. If the Rook ends on a square inside the enemy castle, it is automatically promoted into a Queen.
- A Queens move like a Queen in chess. She is also unimpeded by walls or castles.
- The mutual right of capture between two pieces (except for the King) exists if, and only if, one piece is on the enemy's wall, and the other piece is in their own castle. Otherwise, pieces simply block each other.
- The King may capture pieces inside his castle, provided he can attack the piece (remember that the King can move both as a King and as a Knight).
- Check occurs if the King is in the path of a Rook or Queen, regardless of whether the Rook or Queen is on the wall or not. Walls do not block checks.
- As in regular chess, white moves first, a capturing piece replaces the piece captured, and checkmate wins the game.
- A draw occurs if:

  - *x* moves have passed without any piece being captured.
  - There is three or less pieces on the board.
  - It is a stalemate.

This is a king-of-the-hill Chad competition. To enter write a program that decides what moves to make, using the IO format below. This program will be pitted against other entrants to find out which program is the strongest.

### Inputs and Outputs

Your program will be ran from the command line for each move, and input will be given as a command line argument. Here is the input format:

```
[colour] [board] [history] [moves]
```

- `[color]` is `0` if you are playing White, and `1` if you are playing Black.
- `[board]` is an ASCII representation of the board with newlines stripped. `K` is a King, `R` is a Rook. Lowercase letters indicate black, uppercase means white. A dot `.` is a blank space. The starting position would look like this:

  ```
   ...............................rrr.........rkr.........rrr................RRR.........RKR.........RRR...............................
  ```
- `[history]` is a comma separated list of the moves you and your oppoment have done. It is in a modified long algebraic notation, consisting of the starting and ending squares separated by a hyphen, *without* a letter identifer for the piece. If it is a capture, the hyphen is replaced with an `x`. There is no `!?` or other such ornaments. This is *blank* if you are White and making the first move - be prepared for this!
- `[moves]` is a comma separated list of the valid moves you can make in your current situation. It is also in the modified long algebraic notation.

Note that you don't have to use all of the information given in the input if you do not want to. The information is supplied to simplify the process of making the program.

You program should output a single move in the modified long algebraic notation, indicating what move you want to make on that turn. The move must be valid. The program must output its move within *y* seconds, otherwise it will resign. If the program outputs anything other than a valid move, it will be counted as a resignation.

### Entering

To enter, submit an answer with the following information:

- The **name** of the bot (to be used for score tables, etc.)
- The **language** the bot is written in
- The **command line command** needed to run the bot

If I cannot include your bot for any reason, I will add a comment explaining why I cannot. I will endeavour to install any programs required to run your bot, as long as it is legally free to access (sorry Mathematica people).

The **final round** will occur on xxxx/xx/xx. It is a round robin. Each bot plays against each other bot two times - once as black, and once as white. If a bot wins both rounds, it gains 1 point. If it wins one round, it gains 0.5 points. If it doesn't win either, it gains 0 points. The bot with the most points gets the green checkmark.

I will also hold regular practice rounds, of which you may find the results of here. The last practice round was held on xxxx/xx/xx. These practice rounds will continue even after the final round has finished.

### Questions

- Is the explanation of Chad's rules clear?
- What would be good values for *x* and *y*?
- Would the extra information in the input be helpful?
- Any other advice would be appreciated.

I haven't written the control program yet. I intend on getting the specification ironed out first.

Comment: I'm sad to see this sort of thing here rather than elsewhere where it might find more long term interest.

Comment: I strongly suggest that before posting to live you set up a github repo with the control framework, a sample bot, and a build script which builds all of the bots. See https://github.com/pjt33/ppcg36515 . I also have a suggestion which I've been mulling over with respect to koth in general: round robin emphasises the metagame over actual good play. How about having round robin for seeding purposes followed by a best-of-5 knock-out bracket?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@PeterTaylor When I finish the control framework I'll put it in a github repo. A tournament bracket sounds interesting - I'll try it on this KOTH and we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Hi, this seems like a fun KOTH challengw. Is it still in the works?

Comment: @AndoDaan Yes it is. I'm still writing the control framework. The problem was that before writing the challenge I didn't actually know how to program, so ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I have to learn how to program before I can make the control framework.

Comment: Cool. Big task to start in, but I can imagine you'll get to know all the nooks and crannies of your 1st language. Have fun, and don't get disheartened!

Answer (score 1):

## King of the Tournaments

This game is based off of [Graph Theory Tournaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory))

The competition will be a series of tournaments, where the Kings of a tournament will play in the next until the winner(s) is found

Every player will play every other player exactly once in a tournament.  Each player will recieve `5*N` points each tournament (where `N` is the number of opponents in that tournament).  Furthermore, each player will have an advantage over `N/2` players, and a disadvantage to `N/2` players. This advantage is decided at the beginning of the game.

Each battle will consist of a player commiting `X` points.  Whoever commits more points will win that battle.  If both players commit the same amount of points, the player with the advantage over the other will win.

After a tournament, the Kings will be the players that *defeat* all other players.  `P1` *defeats* `P2` if `P1` beat `P2` in battle, or if `P1` beat a player that beat `P2`.  If all players are kings, then the players with the least amounts of wins this tournament are eliminated.  If all have the same amount of wins, then the players with the least amount of *total* wins are eliminated.  In the case of a tie, the remaining players are declared the winners

## IO

Your bot must stay alive throughout the entire game.  You will pass in a number every round through STDOUT.  You may pass in a few codes through STDOUT to recieve information via STDIN:

`W` will return IDs of the players you have won to this tournament

`L` will return the IDs of the players you have lost to this tournament

`OW` will return the IDs of the players your opponent has won this tournament

`OL` will return the IDs of the players your opponent has lost to this tournament

`A` will return 1 if you have an advantage over the player, else 0

`H` will return the history of your battles against the player.  The list will be comma-seperated, where each battle is represented by `Num1/Num2` where Num1 is the points you committed, and Num2 is the points your opponent committed.

Comment: 1. It be probably be clearer to say that "*In layman's terms, it represents* the outcome of *a round-robin tournament*". 2. What's the connection between the two introductory paragraphs and the third one? I can't follow your train of thought here at all. 3. Each player plays each other player twice per round, on turns `D` and `N-D` where `D` is the difference between their positions?

Answer (score 1):

**Pointlessly Restrictive Integers**

*[COMPLETE. Currently proofreading. Waiting for upvotes / objections before posting.]*

*In this question, all code blocks are independent of each other.*

I'm designing a new programming language called *Pointlessly Restrictive*. The integers in Pointlessly Restrictive work in a peculiar fashion:

1. An integer must be *explicitly declared* with its length before being used (there is one exception to this rule, described below). This is done using the syntax `A = [x]`, where `A` is the name of the integer (always a single, uppercase character) and `x` is the length of the integer. For instance:

   ```
   A = [2]
   B = [5]
   ```

   This declares an integer `A` of length 2, and an integer `B` of length 5. Note that at this point, the actual digits of the integer are not defined - so any integer of the specified length is a possible value. For example:

   ```
   A = 23
   ```

   is an invalid statement, because I haven't declared the variable with its length before using it.
2. The length of an integer is immutable. For instance:

   ```
   A = [5]
   A = [3]
   ```

   is invalid, because I cannot change the length of an integer after making it.
3. Values are assigned to an integer using the syntax `B = x`. For instance:

   ```
   B = [5]
   B = 21436
   ```

   is a valid assignment. Note that:

   ```
   B = [5]
   B = 314
   ```

   would be invalid, because the values given is inconsistent with the specified length of 5.
4. The `+` operator only *concatenates* integers, as if they were strings. For instance:

   ```
   A = [3]
   A = 123
   B = [2]
   B = 45
   C = A + B
   ```

   `C`, in this case, is equal to `12345`. Note that I didn't need to declare the length of `C` before using it – the length is instead decided based on the component integers. In addition, I can use the `[x]` notation in this definition method:

   ```
   A = [3]
   A = 123
   C = A + [2]
   ```

   Any integer that has length 5 and begins with `123` is a possible value for `C`. In addition, if I use an integer twice in this definition method, it must hold the same value each time:

   ```
   A = [2]
   C = A + A + A
   D = C + [2]
   ```

   Any integer that consists of a subsequence of length 2 repeated three times (for instance, `161616`) is a possible value for `C`. That possible value, with any two numbers after it, would be a possible value for `D` (e.g. `16161623`). For instance, the sequence `142632` could not be `C`.
5. A value is printed by baldly printing the name of the integer on one line. If there are unknown digits, it substitutes lower case letters - the letters that are chosen are up to the interpreter. If there are more than 26 lower case letters required (e.g. `A = [27]`), it is an error.

   ```
   A = [2]
   A = 14
   A
   ```

   outputs `14`. Another example:

   ```
   A = [3]
   A = 163
   B = A + [1]
   B
   ```

   outputs `163a`.

   ```
   A = [3]
   B = A + A + [1]
   B
   ```

   outputs `abcabcde`

   Note that the `abc` repeats because the A repeats.
6. Integers can be reassigned, specialised, or generalised at any time. For instance:

   ```
   A = [2]
   A = 13
   B = A + [1]
   ```

   B is equal to `13a`. This is also possible:

   ```
   A = [2]
   A = 13
   B = A + [1]
   B = 134
   ```

   On the fourth line, I have specialised B to a specific value. This is also possible:

   ```
   A = [2]
   A = 13
   B = A + 1
   B = [3]
   ```

   On the fourth line, I have generalised B to make it less specific. However, note that I *cannot* change the length of the integer - so `B = [4]` there would have been invalid.

Pointlessly Restrictive requires each statement to be on its own line. There is no semicolons at the end of lines.

Your task is to write an interpreter for Pointlessly Restrictive. It should be runnable from the command line - as its input, it will be given a filename, which can be assumed to be in the working directory of the operating system. The file contains some Pointlessly Restrictive statements. Your interpreter should check for any errors in the file (for instance, an assignment with the incorrect length), and output `Error!` if there is an error.

If there are no errors in the file, output whatever values are printed in the file.

**Sample Inputs and Outputs**

Input:

```
A = [2]
A = 13
A
```

Output:

```
13
```

Input:

```
A = [2]
A = 13
B = A + A
B
```

Output:

```
1313
```

Input:

```
C = [4] + [2] + [3]
C
```

Output:

```
abcdefghi
```

Input:

```
J = [2]
J = 13
L = [4]
L = 143 + [1]
K = L + J
K
```

Output:

```
143a13
```

Input:

```
J = [2]
K = J + J + J
K = 231323
K
```

Output:

```
Error!
```

Input:

```
J = [2]
K = J + J + J
L = K + [3]
K
L
```

Output:

```
abababcde
```

**Notes**

- Spaces do not hold any syntactic value in Pointlessly Restrictive - `A = [2]` is equivalent to `A=[2]`, `A= [2]`, or even `A=[ 2   ]`.
- This means that the integer `123 54` is the same thing as `12354` for your interpreter.

Comment: Judging from your output in section 6, "all possible values" means `0-9`. You might want to state that limit more clearly. Now it just says "Arrays can only store integers," which is a lot broader.

Comment: @Geobits Thinking about it, it probably makes more sense if I make it storage of integers instead of arrays. Will change when I have time.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Two more things (I think) you didn't specify: can values be reassigned? And can I specialise an integer later one? E.g. at the end of your very last example, could I do `K = 143913`?

Comment: This simply looks like string operations, where [#] defaults to lowercase letters.  The hardest part of this challenge is validating if `A = 123` is valid.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I will agree it's not a difficult challenge. I feel that the number validation part is enough to create some interesting answers however.

Comment: @Lilac Did you address my last comment?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes for both.

Answer (score 1):

## Thinking about the Box outside of the Box

### (looking for input from community)

Everyone has heard about the 9 points 4 lines challenge, where the goal is to connect all the points on a 3x3 grid with only 4 straight line segments, and without lifting your pen.

It has been proven that it is simple to calculate the minimum number of lines needed for any square:

[image: Example]

Write a program that takes 2 positive integers as inputs, the dimensions of the grid of points (x points wide, y points tall) and calculates the minimum number of straight consecutive line segments needed to join all of the points on the grid.

The line segments may go off of the grid of points. (obviously :P)
If either input is 0, output 0. If either input is 1, output 1. Otherwise you have to calculate the result. The inputs can be any positive integer, so hardcoding the solution is impossible.

Your program is correct until proven wrong. Only one counterexample on one set of dimensions is enough to prove a program wrong. (lets say a program outputs 5 for the set x=3, y=3, and the real solution is 4, then the entire program is wrong and it is not counted)

This is a code-golf challenge, shortest code to fulfill the requirements wins.

Comment: It sounds good, but I don't know if this problem has a known closed-form solution which might make it quite trivial.

Comment: The "correct until proven wrong" thing doesn't sit well with me. I think that you should first post a question on [puzzling.stackexchange.com](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) asking whether there exists a closed form solution. I hypothesise a very simple one, but I don't have time now to prove it, but if I'm correct then this would be a very boring question once the first person posts it.

Comment: hmm, maybe requiring them to output the lines could be more challenging?

Answer (score 1):

## Play Your Cards Right

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Game Rules

Play your card right is a game played with a pack of 52 cards (no jokers). At the start the deck is shuffled and the dealer will lay a single card on the table. The player  then has to decide if the next card is higher or lower than the card on the table (note that ace is low here).

The dealer then lays another card on the table. If the card is the same as your guess (higher or lower), then you continue the game. If the card is equal to the last or not the same as your guess, all of the cards on the table are put into a separate pile and the game starts again (the cards in the separate pile are completely discounted).

You lose the game when the deck is emptied. You win the game if you get six cards on the table.

### Challenge

Given the last card to be laid on the table you must make a guess as to whether the next card will be higher or lower.

### Specifics

The necessary information will be supplied via argv:

- If the argument is `newGame` then wipe all data stored about the previous game
- If the argument is `clearTable` then clear the table and move all cards to the separate pile
- If the argument is not detailed above then it is a card name: 1 to 10 or J,Q,K,A

You may store information. I will be testing this on Ubuntu 12.04.

### Winning

The shortest code wins. Please note that these have to be optimal solutions (winning most of the games played by the following controller)

***Controller coming tomorrow (8/10)***

Comment: Should this be code golf? The way it's scored now, everyone will tie because the optimal solution is pretty easy. If the flipped card is higher than half of the remaining cards, guess low. Otherwise, guess high.

Comment: What is the difference between newGame, loseGame, and winGame? Are we supposed to keep track of our losses and wins?

Comment: @Rainbolt Good point, there isn't a difference.

Comment: Now that it's code golf you do need to mention that solutions must implement the optimal strategy. You also might want to write a little controller to probabilistically verify correctness of the submissions.

Comment: A good way to specify "optimal strategy" (short of presenting the algorithm) would be to write a reference implementation of the strategy Rainbolt outlined, running it a few thousand times to measure how often it wins and stating that submissions should achieve that same ratio.

Comment: You say that "*You may store information, but you must not use a file*". But in UNIX, and therefore also in Linux, [*everything* is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Answer (score 1):

## Help me sweep the floors

I have to sweep the floor of an MxN foot floor every night, where M and N can be any value between 1 and 1000.  I need to know the most efficient method of sweeping this floor so I can get it done in the least amount of time.

### Rules:

1. Each stroke of the broom clears a 1 square foot area.
2. Each stroke of the broom can be directed in one of 4 directions - North, South, East, or West.  You can represent these as N, S, E, and W, respectively.
3. When I make a stroke, if there is more than 1 unit of dirt on a square, 75% of the dirt will go onto the square directly swept towards, and the remaining 25% will be equally divided among the side squares.  If there is less than 1 unit of dirt, 90% of the dirt will go onto to square swept towards, and the remaining 10% is divided among the side squares.  The back square receives no dirt.  If I sweep into the wall, 75% of the dirt remains on the swept square.  If I sweep adjacent to the wall, there is only one side square.
4. Your program must keep track of the strokes I need to sweep each floor - this is your score.
5. I must stand in a square adjacent to the square I am sweeping.  I can sweep that square in any direction, but I 95% of the time I will sweep to my right or left; otherwise, I brush the dirt into the air and choke or sweep it all over my feet.
6. Each square initially contains 1 unit of dirt.  The floor is considered clean when no square has more than .025 units of dirt remaining on it.
7. When I take a step, I can either step onto an adjacent square or over an adjacent square onto the next square.
8. The floor is considered swept when the remaining dirt is contained in one square on the floor so I can pick it up.
9. I start at any position [0, {0-N}].  Your program must input a value in the range of 0-N on which I start.

Your program must return the minimum number of steps and strokes I take to sweep this floor.  It may not backtrack and do some steps over, but it can use look-ahead - it must simulate sweeping the floor in actual life.  It must take as input M and N, as well as a value in the range of 0-N specifying where the door is, and output to the screen how many strokes I must take to sweep the floor.  Your score is the number of strokes I must take.  The program that returns the lowest number of strokes for any input is the winner.  Ties will be won by the smallest program character-wise.  Your program will be disqualified if you do not explain the algorithm used in the answer.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: How is it possible to remove dirt from the room? Also missing: a running time limit; initial position of the sweeper; which values of M and N programs will be judged on.

Comment: @feersum M and N can be any value between 1 and 1000. The dirt must be swept into a pile on 1 square so I can put it in the dust pan, and does there need to be a runtime limit?

Comment: If you don't have a runtime limit you're going to get mostly exponential-time solutions searching for the optimal solution, which you can't possibly run to completion.

Comment: How will I define a limit?  I can't run every program on my computer.

Comment: Why can't you run every program? I suggest the running time should be shorter than the age of the universe on some computer that currently exists.

Comment: Why?  I don't have a compiler for every language on my computer, and I certainly can't buy Mathematica.  I agree that the running time should be reasonable, but I don't understand big O notation yet...

Comment: @hosch250 Don't worry about the big O complexity or running all the answers. Requiring that programs run within some time limit on [some reference computer](https://teksyndicate.com/forum/general-discussion/average-steam-users-computer-specs/150190) is perfectly acceptable. Though if the answers *have* to be optimal doing things in a time limit may be impossible.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Thanks.  So I should just specify that if it runs within that time limit, people can calculate or guess if it is likely to, and that will work?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this earlier but they suggested I put it in the sandbox which made a lot of sense.

## Reading sheet music

Your job is to take an image of sheet music and make it usefull for someone that doesn't read notes.

#### Output

```
3/4 (Which is the beat)
C F B,A,D E F C (Notes, Space seperated and comma seperated if notes are tied)
Images of the notes to play.
```

Layout images:
The images must show a piano with the layout of an 61 key piano.
[image: 61 key piano layout]

Each image will display a set of 5 consecutive notes. Tied notes will be treated as 1 note.
If the first note of a set is C there will be a '1' on the C key,
Second note F there will be a '2' on the F key and so on.
Like i said tied notes will be treated as 1 note but the index will count up.
So `B,A,D` will result in:
'1' on `B`; '2' on `A`; '3' on `D`.

If the same note is used twice in 1 set the note will show both indexes.
How you display that is up to you, you can either seperate them by comma or newline.

Some information on reading notes can be found here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Read-Music
http://readsheetmusic.info/readingmusic.shtml

Submitted answers must have:

- The code (Golfed and ungolfed).
- Image used (or link to image).
- The output (both text and images).

Not sure about the tag. I tagged it [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) for now but if someone has a better idea let me know.
(should I also use the [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) tag?)

Right now this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the one with the lowest bytes wins.

Happy coding :)

Comment: To reiterate what was said in the comments, (i) this is a seriously hard challenge. Programs will be very complex and not so fun to golf, so it's probably better to make a winning criterion based purely on accuracy. This will probably involve providing a definitive set of test images; (ii) you need to figure out how to avoid 'workarounds' where people just hash the test images you provide. (For example, keep some test images hidden until it's time to judge the winner - though that does make it time limited.)

Comment: (iii) this is really two challenges, the easy graphical output challenge and the very very hard OCR-for-sheet-music challenge. It would probably be better to stick to just one of them, and have either text-based input or text-based output. I think that was about it.

Comment: Nice idea, but honestly I think the reverse challenge (input notes in scientific pitch notation and output a musical score) would work better. EDIT: Oops, what I'm suggesting has already been done: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24783/15599

Answer (score 1):

## 5 Miscellaneous Flag Challenges [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

We've had questions on [the South Korean flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40052/draw-the-south-korean-flag) and [the flag of Nepal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/lets-draw-flag-of-nepal). I thought that some other flag questions could be interesting.

I've grouped these into one post to avoid cluttering the sandbox with potentially bad posts. Once we've decided which of these are worth doing challenges for, I'll separate them out into separate posts, and make exact specifications of what it should look like.

Flag pictures taken from [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/), which is in the public domain.

How much hardcoding should be allowed, if any? Is it better to decide on a per-flag basis?

Your task is to output the flag, to a file, STDOUT or the screen, in any common format (SVG, PostScript, RAW, PNG).

### Malawi

[image: Malawi flag]

**Pros:** Relatively simple
**Cons:** The "beams of sunlight" may need to be simplified slightly as they are some weird shape that I don't even know a name for

## Saint Pierre and Miquelon

[image: Saint Pierre and Miquelon flag]

**Pros:** Quite a lot of repetition. Complex but not impossible. Probably fun.
**Cons:** That ship and the lions are going to be quite difficult - probably need to be simplified a bit

## Australia

[image: Australia flag]

**Pros:** Simple geometric shapes. There's nothing hugely overcomplicated here. Some repetition. Shouldn't be too hard.
**Cons:** The stars have already appeared in the Nepal question - there is some overlap.

### Mongolia

[image: Mongolia flag]

**Pros:** Simple geometric shapes (mostly), but quite a lot of them.
**Cons:** The yin-yang bit is similar to the South Korean flag, which we've done already

### Togo

[image: Togo flag]

**Pros:** Simple
**Cons:** Maybe too simple?

Comment: The problem with Saint Pierre and Miquelon will be to specify the shapes exactly enough to make this a good code golf. I also think that Togo is too trivial, as is Malawi. The others could be interesting. Another one I had in mind was [Brazil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Brazil#mediaviewer/File:Flag_of_Brazil.svg).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Brazil is interesting, I almost forgot that one - can I add that to the list or do you want to post that one yourself? You could simplify Saint Pierre and Miquelon by turning all the curves into circle arcs and getting rid of bits such as the white curves in the sea. The crow's nest could just be a rectangle. I'm not sure my GIMP abilities go that far though...

Comment: I don't intend to post another flag any time soon. It's good fun, but it will get boring if we have one of these every week. There are only a limited number of interesting flags, so I don't see a point in exhausting them for challenges quickly.

Comment: There are many flags based on the UK flag besides Australia, listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack. Wikpedia has the spec of the UK (it was used as a tutorial in the Sinclair ZX Spectrum manual back in the 80's.) Maybe do the Union jack first and the other flags of the family as a follow-up. The spec of the Australian flag inevitably refers back to the Union Jack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Australia but I think Australia is about the right level of complexity. Another (rather simple) family of flags is the Scandinavian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Cross_flag.

Comment: The Scandinavian ones might make sense in a single challenge with a parameter.

Comment: @MartinBüttner that was my thought about the Scandinavian ones too, but even so, it's very simple. How to make it more complicated: a guessing game?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like the flag of Hawaii as a challenge from the Union Jack family. It's slightly easier than the Australian flag, and has the appeal of being not particularly well known. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Hawaii

Comment: I've upvoted now, because I think enough time has passed since Martin's Korean flag challenge. I do believe it's important to use the authentic specification for flag drawing challenges. With that in mind, are you going to go ahead with Australia (or Hawaii?) The reason I ask is because I've thought of another flag challenge (unrelated to national flags.)  BTW, I think St Pierre & Miquelon is too hard to draw, let alone specify, but it might work if you designed a nice ASCII art representation to generate.

Comment: A codegolf in itself would be to take a flag and make it into a waving flag animation. A standard challenge in computer graphics since the old days, but we don't see too many CG golfing challenges here.

Answer (score 1):

## Multi-File Code Golf

This is a new challenge Idea. Multi-File Code Golf. The idea is to write your golfed code in more than one file, and your score is the size of the largest file.

## Your Program

You need to fit the specs with a program that spans multiple files. Any languages that use multiple files are valid. For example you could use C++ with a header file, JS/HTML or Ruby with require. files may be named anything you want, and be in any directory.

Score equal to the size of your largest file. (in bytes)

## Chalinge

(Originally I had tic-tac-toe, but I decided that was a bad idea.)
I need a good idea for a challenge that will work well in this format. Any ideas? It needs to be complex enough for multiple files to be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how much the multiple files thing adds to the golfitude. Wouldn't most of your files just be a single statement plus import/include another file? It seems like it could easily boil down to "who has the shortest import statement".

Comment: @Geobits I see your point. would it be better to give a max file count (maybe 5, 10?) I make it a challenge to spread code most evenly?

Comment: Probably better, but I'd wait for input from others who may be more knowledgeable about tricky imports ;)

Comment: Rather than using imports, I think `exec(open("a").read())` or similar might be easier to do

Comment: Tic-tac-toe has been done.

Comment: @Sp3000 In some languages, yes...

Comment: I agree with Peter. The scoring is a novel concept with potential (but not without problems.) But we don't need another tic-tac-toe question.

Answer (score 1):

## Rearrange pixels from one image to form another, with different pixel counts

This would be very similar to [American Gothic in the palette of Mona Lisa: Rearrange the pixels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/american-gothic-in-the-palette-of-mona-lisa-rearrange-the-pixels) except that the images would not necessarily have the same area. If the palette image is larger, then the pixels can be chosen amongst and some left unused. If the palette image is smaller, then the result will be resized/resampled to the same aspect ratio as the other image.

The inspiration for this challenge is a real world application, using limited numbers of colored tiles to make a mosaic copy of a full color image. There would be an unlimited number of white/background tiles, but I can't think of a way to represent that in the challenge description, so I'd probably just fake the number of white tiles for a given target resolution.

Comment: I think you mean *area* rather than *aspect ratio*, but I would vote to close this as a duplicate. Some of the existing answers would need no modification other than to do the rescale to get a large enough palette.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I definitely meant aspect ratio.

Comment: I like problems like this and hope some variation can go live.  However, as currently conceived, the problem is that some way to define how to interpolate a palette of m pixels into another of n pixels is needed, and then given the input is fixed the output is the exact same problem as the "rearrange the pixels" problem?

Comment: @Will it might be more complex than that. since it involves resizing, it could also involve anti-moire algorithms and different priorities in selecting or tweaking dithering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

## Draw the Tree of Life

A [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) contest to render the [tree of life data](http://www.treefam.org/static/download/treefam_species_tree9.phy) (which is in the simple [Newick format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format)) sideways in ASCII, using the same formatting as this example:

```
   __/a
__/  \b
  \   _/c
   \_/ \d
     \e
```

Note that the *distance* in the source data is ignored; the tree should be drawn as compact as possible.

The source data can be fed into the program via stdin or by opening a file or as a parameter to a function.  The output should be printing to stdout.

The output should not be hard-coded; the tree data must be read in and parsed by the program.

Actually printing a tree on its side is itself a bit of a coding challenge; see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096134/print-a-binary-tree-on-its-side) for inspiration.

Comment: Is this a contest to make a program which can render general trees from Newick format to the sideways ASCII format, or does it only have to work on the one data set? If it's the general form, does that data set test all the corner cases?

Comment: @PeterTaylor its to render this particular data set.

Answer (score 1):

## Traders for life

In this game, each bot will own a factory that accepts `N` products, and can produce `M` of a different product, denoted by `#,Input->#,Output`.  There are 3 products `A`,`B`, and `C` and three types of factories, `A->B`, `B->C`, and `C->A`.  Each factory of the same type will input the same number of products, and outputs the same number of products.  Each both will be assigned a factory type, which can be queried (as described below) Producing `A->B->C->A` will increase the total amount of `A`.

**Example:** Bot 1's factory is `5A->2B`, and starts with 500A.  Bot 2's factory is `3B->7C` and starts with 300B.  Bot 3's factory is `5C->6A` and starts with 500C.

You start with `$1000`, and your goal is to increase that money.  Each turn you will produce, buy, and then sell in that order.

To produce you will pass in the number of inputs.  If you pass in more inputs than you currently have in inventory, then you will only produce what you have in inventory.  If the amount input isn't divisible, then a remainder of your input will remain which couldn't be produced.

To sell, you will pass the type you want to sell, the price, and the max amount you will sell.  To buy, you will pass the type you want to buy, the max you will pay for it, and the max amount you will buy.  The buyer with the highest max price will then be paired up with the seller with the highest price that is under the buyer's price.  The buyer will then buy as many products as possible at the seller's price.  If the seller reaches his maximum of products to sell, then the buyer will continue to buy from the next seller.  If the buyer reaches his maximum of products to buy, then the seller will continue to sell his product to the buyer with the next highest maximum price.

All products and dollar amounts are integers (there are no cents or partial products).

There will be 3 copies of each bot, each assigned to a different factory.  These bots cannot communicate with each other or with any other bot.

The player with the most money across all of their bots after 500 rounds wins.

Any language can be used, and input/output will come through STDIO.  If you wanted to produce 34 of your product, buy 10 of product A at the price $5 and sell 20 of product `B` at the price of $6, then you would pass in `P,34 B,A,10,5 S,B,20,6`.

At any time you can pass in:

`I` to query your inventory, which will return something like `5A 10B 8C`

`M` to query the amount of money you have

`T` to query your history of trades.  It will be a space delimited list of trades.  Each trade will look like like `B,1275,A,49,90` (You bought from player #1275 49 of product `A` at the price of $90) or `S,385,B,29,30` (You sold to player #385 29 of product `B` at the price of $30).

`R` to query the number of rounds left

`F` to query your factory type. It will return something like `5A->2B`

Comment: How do you initialize the factories? A random initialization may give some bots much better factories than others.

Comment: They are initialized randomly, but because there is no dollar amount attached to a factory, theres no way to say which factory has the advantage.

Comment: Well, intuitively I'd say that `2A->4B` has an advantage over `4A->2B`, and it's difficult to say how big the advantage is, since it depends on all the other bots' factories. I think it might be better to give every team the same set of factories, or the game will be very difficult to balance, since a bot is stuck with its factory for the entire run.

Comment: The example you proposed wouldn't ever happen, at least in the same game.  All bots with an `A` factory will have the same production ratios.

Comment: Ok, I had misunderstood you, this makes much more sense now. Still, if a player optimizes their bots for some specific factory configuration, their success depends heavily on the random initialization. Perhaps it would be worth running the simulation on some finite number of sufficiently different (predefined?) factory configurations, and taking the average score from those to determine the winner.

Answer (score 1):

## Smuggle these Pincodes

After many years, our covert agent has managed to amass a list of all [PIN codes](http://paste2.org/O68MAyL9) in an enemy nation.

But there is a complication. The government of the country did become aware of our actions. Now our agent needs to smuggle the PINs past the customs without being caught!

Our spy needs help. Hiding a list of 10 000 codes will be too difficult. Luckily, our government can enlist the help of its loyal programmers (*you!*).

### The Challenge

Write a program that will output a list of all PIN codes from `0000` up to `9999` (inclusive). The program needs to be as short as possible to get past customs unnoticed.

#### Rules

- The PINs must each be on a separate line.
- The program may not output anything other than the required output. However, it *may* output one (and no more than one) line end after the last PIN; e.g. `9999\n`.

And, in case you were wondering:

- Your program **must not**:

  - Depend on any external resources.
  - Depend on having a specific file name.
  - Take exceptionally long to run. If your program runs over a minute on an average home user’s computer, it’s invalid.
  - Be written in a programming language for which there did not exist a publicly available compiler / interpreter before this challenge was posted.

[An example of the correct output can be seen here](http://paste2.org/O68MAyL9).

#### Scoring

The shortest code (in bytes, in any language) wins.

Any non-standard command-line arguments (arguments that aren’t normally required to run a script) count towards the total character count.

Your program’s output *may* deviate from the given list order, in which case your program’s byte count will incur a **+10%** penalty (rounded up).

Comment: "You may assume your program won't receive invalid input." Why would it receive any input at all? What exactly is "valid" input here?

Comment: @FireFly I copied that line from a previous question without realizing that the program does not receive any input. I have removed it.

Comment: Isn't this a bit trivial? It's just printing numbers from 0 to 9999 which are padded two 4 characters. Or printing the numbers from 10000 to 19999, ditching the leading 1, if you like. (Nothing against simple challenges, but I'm not sure how much room for optimisation this leaves.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I realize it's a very simple challenge. I could not find any duplicates however, so I decided to put it in the sandbox anyway. But yes, there isn't much left to optimize, other than the things you mention and choosing the right programming language for the job. If there is consensus that it's *too* easy I can try to make it more challenging (or delete it).

Comment: I think it's too easy. A golfer could write an optimal solution in 5 minutes.

Comment: Easy questions give less experienced programmers another opportunity to participate. I'd still make it more challenging before you post it, but I don't think being easy is bad.

Answer (score 1):

## Writing the Hydra Function

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

---

## Preamble

Sometime in the early 21st century, computer scientists would discover the Hydra function (also known as the Lächerlich function), `f`, whose signature is given by

```
R = f( A, B, L, x, y, z )
```

where `A`, `B`, `L`, and `R` are finite integers, and `x`, `y`, and `z` are integers in the range [-2<sup>31</sup>  2<sup>31</sup>).

The function would quickly rise to preeminence due to the fact that it can perform 40 *useful and well-known* binary operations on `A` and `B`, returning the result in `R`. These operations are listed in the section "Operations" below, which provides a rigorous description of each.

It is important to note here that "integer" refers to the mathematical concept of an integer. In particular, there is no concept of integer overflow or of binary representation. In the case of variables `A`, `B`, and `L`, integer values are unbounded. In the case of `x`, `y`, `z`, the variables may not violate their explicit bound; any operation that could potentially assign an out-of-range value to these variables is an error and forbidden.

## Operations

The following code snippet defines all 40 (potential) operations of `f`. In each case, a name, description, and precise mathematical definition is provided. As a convenience, each operation also includes a C function that (notwithstanding data type bounds) implements the operation when compiled by `gcc`. In all cases, the mathematical definition should be considered authoritative.

```html
<style>tr:nth-child(4n-3) td:first-child { width: 150px; font: bold 24px Times New Roman,Times,serif; }</style><style>tr:nth-child(4n-2) span { font-family: Courier New,monospace; }</style><style>tr:nth-child(4n) { font-family: Courier New,monospace; white-space:pre; }</style><style>tr:nth-child(4n) td { padding-bottom: 50px; }</style><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script><div>Note that \(\left\lfloor\frac{A}{B}\right\rfloor _0\) indicates "divide and truncate towards zero", and that \(\operatorname{sgn}\left( x\right)\) indicates the signum function evaluated at \(x\).<br><br>Also note that for operations conditionally returning \({\rm anything}\), "anything" may be any value representable as an integer, or a fatal error. "Anything" does not have to be consistent from operation to operation. You may rely on the results returned for "anything" in subsequent calculations.</div><hr><br><br><div id="main">1. 0 [Constant 0] (0) \[R = 0\cdot A + 0\cdot B\] {{return 0;}} 2. 1 [Constant 1] (1) \[R = 1 + 0\cdot A + 0\cdot B\] {{return 1;}} 3. 2 [Constant 2] (2) \[R = 2 + 0\cdot A + 0\cdot B\] {{return 2;}} 4. A [Value of A] (A) \[R = A + 0\cdot B\] {{return A;}} 5. A + B [Sum of A and B] (sum) \[R = A + B\] {{return A + B;}} 6. A - B [Difference of A and B] (diff) \[R = A - B\] {{return A - B;}} 7. AB [Product of A and B] (prod) \[R = AB\] {{return A*B;}} 8. A &#247; B [Truncated Quotient of A by B] (div) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}B = 0} \\!!{\left\lfloor {\frac{A}{B}} \right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A/B;}} 9. A &#247; B Remainder [Remainder after Division of A by B] (rem) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}B = 0} \\!!{A - B\left\lfloor {\frac{A}{B}} \right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A % B;}} 10. A modulo |B| [A Modulo |B|] (mod) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}B = 0} \\!!{A\operatorname{mod} \left| B\right|}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{   int X, Q;!!   X = B < 0 ? -B : B;!!   Q = A % X;!!   return Q < 0 ? Q + X : Q;}} 11. A = B [A Equals B] (is) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}A = B} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A == B;}} 12. |A| > |B| [A is of Greater Magnitude than B] (gmag) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left| A\right| > \left| B\right|} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (A > 0 ? A : -A) > (B > 0 ? B : -B);}} 13. A &and; B [Both A and B are Nonzero] (and) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( A \neq 0\right) \wedge \left( B \neq 0\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A && B;}} 14. A &or; B [Either A or B is Nonzero] (or) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( A \neq 0\right) \vee \left( B \neq 0\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A || B;}} 15. A &#8891; B [Either A or B is Nonzero, but Not Both] (xor) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( A \neq 0\right) \wedge \left( B = 0\right)} \\!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( A = 0\right) \wedge \left( B \neq 0\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (A != 0) ^ (B != 0);}} 16. A<sup>B</sup> [A to the Power of B] (pow) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{A^B}&{{\rm{if\ }}B \geq 0\rm{\ or\ }\left| A\right| = 1} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (int)pow( A, B );}} 17. &#189;(A + B) [Average (Arithmetic Mean) of A and B] (avg) \[R = \left\lfloor\frac{A + B}{2}\right\rfloor _0\] {{return (A + B)/2;}} 18. A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> [Sum of Squares of A and B] (sumsqs) \[R = A^2 + B^2\] {{return A*A + B*B;}} 19. A<sup>2</sup> - B<sup>2</sup> [Difference of Squares of A and B] (diffsqs) \[R = A^2 - B^2\] {{return A*A - B*B;}} 20. &#189;((-1)<sup>A</sup> - (-1)<sup>B</sup>) [Synchronicity of A and B] (sync) \[R = \left( -1\right)^A - \left( -1\right)^B\] {{return (int)(pow( -1, A ) - pow( -1, B ));}} 21. |A + B| [Absolute Sum of A and B] (abssum) \[R = \left| A + B\right|\] {{return A + B < 0 ? -(A + B) : (A + B);}} 22. |A - B| [Distance from A to B] (dist) \[R = \left| A - B\right|\] {{return A < B ? (B - A) : (A - B);}} 23. max( A, B ) [Maximum of A and B] (max) \[R = \max\left( A, B\right)\] {{return A > B ? A : B;}} 24. min( A, B ) [Minimum of A and B] (min) \[R = \min\left( A, B\right)\] {{return A < B ? A : B;}} 25. minmod( A, B ) [Minmod Limiter] (minmod) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\min\left( A, B\right)}&{{\rm{if\ }}A > 0 {\rm\ and\ } B > 0} \\!!{\max\left( A, B\right)}&{{\rm{if\ }}A < 0 {\rm\ and\ } B < 0} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{   if( A > 0 && B > 0 )!!      return A < B ? A : B;!!   if( A < 0 && B < 0 )!!      return A > B ? A : B;!!   return 0;}} 26. A ? B : 0 [Return B Conditionally] (condb) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{B}&{{\rm{if\ }}A \neq 0} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A ? B : 0;}} 27. &#189;(A + B)(|B - A| + 1) [Sum of Integers from A to B] (sumatob) \[R = \frac{\left( A + B\right)\left( \left| B - A\right| + 1\right)}{2}\] {{return (A + B)*((B < A ? (A - B) : (B - A)) + 1)/2;}} 28. A <<<sub>2</sub> B [Left-shift A by B Zeroes in Binary] (rsh) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{2^B A}&{{\rm{if\ }}B \geq 0} \\!!{\left\lfloor\frac{A}{2^{-B}}\right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return B >= 0 ? A*(1 << B) : A/(1 << -B);}} 29. A <<<sub>10</sub> B [Left-shift A by B Zeroes in Decimal] (rsh10) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{10^B A}&{{\rm{if\ }}B \geq 0} \\!!{\left\lfloor\frac{A}{10^{-B}} \right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (int)A*pow( 10, B );}} 30. A + sgn(B - A) [Increment A Towards B] (twrdb) \[R = A + \operatorname{sgn}\left( B - A \right)\] {{return A + (B > A) - (B < A);}} 31. |A| sgn(B) [Magnitude of A with the Phase of B] (magphs) \[R = \left| A\right|\operatorname{sgn}\left( B\right)\] {{return (A < 0 ? -A : A)*((B > 0) - (B < 0));}} 32. |A| > |B| ? A : B [Return Furthest From Zero: A or B] (ffzero) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!! {A\rm{\ or\ }B}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left| A\right| = \left| B\right|} \\!!{A}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left| A\right| > \left| B\right|} \\!!{B}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (A < 0 ? -A : A) > (B < 0 ? -B : B) ? A : B;}} 33. gcd( |A|, |B| ) [Greatest Common Denominator of A and B] (gcd) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}A = 0\rm{\ or\ }B = 0} \\!!{\operatorname{gcd}\left( {\left| A\right| , \left| B\right|}\right)}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{   int X, Y, T;!!   X = A < 0 ? -A : A;!!   Y = B < 0 ? -B : B;!!   while( Y != 0 ) {!!      T = Y;!!      Y = X % Y;!!      X := T;!!   }!!   return X;}} 34. lcm( |A|, |B| ) [Least Common Multiple of A and B] (lcm) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}A = 0\rm{\ or\ }B = 0} \\!!{\frac{AB}{\operatorname{gcd}\left( {\left| A\right| , \left| B\right|}\right)}}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{   int X, Y, T, P;!!   X = A < 0 ? -A : A;!!   Y = B < 0 ? -B : B;!!   P = X*Y;!!   while( Y != 0 ) {!!      T = Y;!!      Y = X % Y;!!      X := T;!!   }!!   return P/X;}} 35. A*B/(A + B) [Harmonic Mean of A and B] (harm) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}A + B = 0} \\!!{\left\lfloor\frac{AB}{A + B}\right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return A*B/(A + B);}} 36. max(-|B|,min(|B|,A)) [Value of A Clipped to +/-|B|] (clip) \[R = \max\left( -\left| B\right| , \min\left( \left| B\right| , A\right)\right)\] {{   int X;!!   X = B < 0 ? -B : B;!!   return A < -B ? -B : (A > B : B : A);}} 37. A|B| - B|A| [Commutator Bracket of A and B] (comm) \[R = A\left| B\right| - B\left| A\right|\] {{return A*B < 0 ? (2*A*B*((B > 0) - (B < 0))) : 0;}} 38. |A| mod 10 = |B| mod 10 [A and B Have Same Last Decimal Digit] (sameldd) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left| A\right| = \left| B\right|\;\;\left(\operatorname{mod} 10\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{   int X, Y;!!   X = A < 0 ? -A : A;!!   Y = B < 0 ? -B : B;!!   return X % 10 == Y % 10;}} 39. (A<sup>B</sup> - 1)/(A - 1) [Sum of First B Terms in Power Series 1 + A + A<sup>2</sup> + ...] (pwrsrs) \[R = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}B < 0} \\!!{\rm{anything}}&{{\rm{if\ }}A \leq 1} \\!!{\frac{A^B - 1}{A - 1}}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}} \right.\] {{return (int)(pow( A, B ) - 1)/(A - 1);}} 40. B<sup>2</sup>/(A<sup>2</sup> + 1) [Squared Distance of the Line Ax + B to the Origin] (sqdist2orgn) \[R = \frac{B^2}{A^2 + 1}\] {{return B*B/(A*A + 1);}}</div><script type="text/javascript">$('#main').html( '<table>' + $('#main').html().replace( /([^\[]+) \[(.+?)\] \((.+?)\) \\\[(.+?)\\\] \{\{(.+?)\}\}/g, '<tr><td>$1</td></tr><tr><td>$2 (<span>$3</span>)</td></tr><tr><td>\\[$4\\]</td></tr><tr><td>$5</td></tr>' ).replace( /!!/g, "\n" ) + '</table>' );</script><script type="text/x-mathjax-config;executed=true">MathJax.Hub.Config( { "HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic: true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"],["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" }}, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" } );</script><script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

## The Nature of `f`

The properties of `f` are summarized as follows:

- The operations in `f` are purchased with operation points (OP) and branching points (BP). `f` is implemented using no more than **120 OP** and no more than **20 BP**.

  OP and BP purchases costs apply once per code element purchased. For example, the code

  ```
  while( A > 0 )
     A = A - B;
  ```

  incurs the costs of one `while` loop, one condition, one assignment, and one binary operation, even if the condition, assignment, and binary operation may be evaluated more than once.
- No unary operations are permitted.
- Constant conditions (e.g. `true`, `false`, or equivalent) are permitted. All non-constant conditions must be explicit (e.g. no `if( A )`).
- Only the binary operations and conditions listed under "Binary Operations and Conditions" are permitted.
- The ternary operation `<condition> ? <iftrue> : <iffalse>` is permitted at the cost of 1 BP plus any cost(s) associated with the operands. Languages that don't explicitly support this ternary operation may implement it as a function.
- `f` must return a result in worst case `O(log max(|A|,|B|))` time or better.
- `f` may recursively invoke itself at a cost of *either* 1 BP or 2 OP, but only to a worst case stack depth of `O(log max(|A|,|B|))` or better.
- The following control structures are permitted in `f`:

  - `if` blocks cost 1 BP each plus the cost of the branch condition
  - `if else` blocks cost 2 BP each plus the cost of the branch condition
  - `if elseif` blocks cost 1 BP per `if`, `elseif`, or `else`, plus the cost(s) of any branch conditions
  - `while` loops and `for` loops cost 2 BP each plus the cost(s) of any initialization, loop condition, and loop update statements
  - `do while` loops cost 1 BP each plus the cost of the loop condition
  - `goto`, `break`, named `break`, `continue`, and named `continue` statements cost 1 BP each
  - `return` statements cost 1 BP each, with the exception of the last top-level `return` that appears in `f`, which costs nothing

  Programming languages that do not support the above structures may implement them as separate functions/methods/closures or as semantically equivalent code. For example, the code

  ```
   while( 1 ) {
      <statement>
      ...
      if( A == B )
         break;
   }
  ```

  is semantically equivalent to the code

  ```
   do {
      <statement>
      ...
   } while( A != B )
  ```

  and hence the former may be used at the cost of 1 BP (the cost of a `do while` loop).

## Variables and Data Types

Variables and data types in `f` are summarized as follows:

- No variables may be defined or used by `f` except for the parameters `A`, `B`, `L`, `x`, `y`, `z`, which may be both read and assigned. Variable assignments may not be chained or nested in expressions (e.g. `A = B = 0`, `w = y == 1 || (z = 10)` are not permitted). If a programming language does not support assignment to parameters, parameters may alternatively be copied into proxy local variables at the start of the function. Once this is done, the original parameters may not be referenced.
- Variable assignment incurs no OP or BP costs.
- Assignment to `x`, `y`, and `z` must respect the strict bounds on these variables. For example, if `A` is not guaranteed to be bounded by [-2<sup>31</sup>  2<sup>31</sup>), the assignment `x = A` is an error and illegal, even if a programming language would ordinarily allow it. The assignment `x = A % 2` (with the semantics of the `%` operator defined below) is legal since all values of `A` are guaranteed to yield a legal value of `x`.

  Note that these same restrictions apply when passing arguments to recursive invocations of `f`.
- It is recommended that `A`, `B`, `L`, `x`, `y`, `z` all be represented using the same type, but this is not a requirement. Implicit casts, explicit casts, method calls, and/or explicit function calls for converting between data types are allowed in all contexts, provided that both:

  - no clipping, truncation, or wraparound occurs as a result of the conversion
  - all operations on all data types are homomorphic to operations on the integers (notwithstanding the limited range of `x`, `y`, and `z`)
- Constants may be defined at no cost, but may only have values in the range [-2<sup>31</sup>  2<sup>31</sup>). Constants with values outside this range can be realized via binary operations (e.g. `123456789*987654321`) but these operations incur costs as normal.

  A constant may be defined using any data type and converted (implicitly or explicitly) to any data type so long as the conversion respects the rules listed above.
- `A`, `B`, `L` are ideally represented by a "big integer" type while `x`, `y`, `z` are best represented as big integers or signed 32-bit `int`s, but these are not requirements. In particular, an implementation of `f` may choose to represent all variables using bounded data types, which is allowable subject to two restrictions:

  - under no circumstances may non-ideal effects such as clipping, truncation, floating point precision errors, etc. be used or exploited in the implementation of `f`
  - any implementation of `f` relying on bounded data types that has these types replaced with unbounded counterparts must function properly over all inputs in this expanded domain

## Binary Operations and Conditions

Only the following set of binary operations and conditions may be used in the implementation of `f`. Each operation/condition has a cost of 1 OP. Operations/conditions may be implemented in any way (e.g. via infix operators, function calls, method calls, etc.) provided they are stateless and they conform exactly to the given definitions.

```html
<style>tr:first-child { font: bold 18px Times New Roman,Times,serif; }</style><style>td { text-align:center; }</style><style>tr:nth-child(2n) { background-color:#eee; }</style><style>tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(3) { font-family: Courier New,monospace; white-space: pre; }</style><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script><div id="main">addition \[x + y\] {{x + y}} subtraction \[x - y\] {{x - y}} multiplication \[xy\] {{x*y}} integer division with truncation towards zero* \[\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor _0\] {{x/y}} remainder of integer division* \[x - y\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor _0\] {{x % y}} modulo** \[x \operatorname{mod} \left| y\right|\] {{int k, q;!!k = y < 0 ? -y : y;!!q = x % k;!!return q < 0 ? q + k : q;}} binary left shift \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{2^y x}&{{\rm{if\ }}y \geq 0} \\!!{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^{-y}} \right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}}\] {{y >= 0 ? x*(1 << y) :!!   x/(1 << -y)}} binary right shift \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^y} \right\rfloor _0}&{{\rm{if\ }}B \geq 0} \\!!{2^{-y} x}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}!!\end{array}}\] {{y >= 0 ? x/(1 << y) :!!   x*(1 << -y)}} logical AND \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( x \neq 0\right) \wedge \left( y \neq 0\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x && y}} logical OR \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}\left( x \neq 0\right) \vee \left( y \neq 0\right)} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x || y}} equality (Dirac delta) \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x = y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x == y}} inequality \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x \neq y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x != y}} less than \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x < y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{r < y}} greater than \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x > y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x > y}} less than or equal to \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x \leq y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x <= y}} greater than or equal to \[{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{1}&{{\rm{if\ }}x \geq y} \\!!{0}&{{\rm{otherwise}}}\end{array}}\] {{x >= y}} bitwise AND of absolutes \[\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}!!{\sum\limits_k {{x_k}{y_k}{2^k}} {\rm{\ given}}} \\!!{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left| x \right| = \sum\limits_k {{x_k}{2^k}} } \\!!{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left| y \right| = \sum\limits_k {{y_k}{2^k}} } \\!!{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{x_k},{y_k} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}\,\,\forall \,k}!!\end{array}\] {{(x < 0 ? -x : x) &   !!(y < 0 ? -y : y)}}</div><hr><div>*division by zero is a fatal error<br>**modulo zero is a fatal error</div><script type="text/javascript">$('#main').html( '<table cellspacing="0"><tr><td>Operation</td><td>Definition</td><td>C Code (gcc)</td></tr>' + $('#main').html().replace( /([^\[]+) \\\[(.+?)\\\] \{\{(.+?)\}\}/g, '<tr><td>$1</td><td>\\[$2\\]</td><td>$3</td></tr>' ).replace( /!!/g, "\n" ) + '</table>' );</script><script type="text/x-mathjax-config;executed=true">MathJax.Hub.Config( { "HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic: true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"],["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" }}, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" } );</script><script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

## Objective

Your objective is to write a function or a program containing a function that implements as many of the 40 operations of `f` as possible. When invoked at the top level, the arguments of `f` are assigned as follows:

- `A` and `B` specify the two general operands for the operation being selected. For any of the 40 listed operations where the result is not symmetric in `A` and `B`, you may return a result for *swapped* `A` and `B` if desired. For example, the function `A + sgn(B - A)` may alternatively return the value of `B + sgn(A - B)`. Operations with swapped operands should be documented in your submission.
- `L` must always be zero when passed to the top level invocation of `f`. Recursive invocations of `f` may pass any legal value to `L`.
- `x`, `y` and `z` collectively specify the operation to be performed. This datum can be encoded any way you desire (respecting the limited range of these parameters). Your submission should include a list of at least one (`x`,`y`,`z`) tuple per implemented operation that causes `f` to compute the result for that operation. You may assume that only these tuples will be passed to a top level invocation of `f`, hence `f` may exhibit arbitrary behaviour (including errors and/or illegal operations) if undocumented tuples are passed to top level invocations.

  As with `L`, recursive invocations of `f` may pass any legal values to `x`, `y`, and `z`. The results of any such intermediary operations need not be documented.

## Scoring

Scoring rules are as follows:

- If `f` *does not* implement all 40 operations, score 10 points per implemented operation plus 1 point per unused BP plus 1 point per unused OP.
- If `f` *does* implement all 40 operations, score 400 points plus 50 points per unused BP plus 25 points unused OP.

The highest scoring submission is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

## Origami Code Golf

I like origami (especially [unit origami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_origami)), but lack the patience to actually complete a project.

Sounds like a wonderful job for a computer!

### Objective

Make a program or function that accepts a series of numbers (see next part) and outputs a folded version of a 1 x 1 square.

### Input

You will receive a list of numbers {a,b,c,d,e,f},{g,h,i,j,k,l}... (curly braces only added for clarity) Each set of numbers corresponds to 3 coordinates (a,b), (c,d) and (e,f). (a,b) and (c,d) each lie on the [unit square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_square) (which also means that it is in the first quadrant). (e,f) lies within the unit square, but on a portion of the paper that is not on the line formed by (a,b) and (c,d).

(a,b) and (c,d) determine the line over which to fold the paper.

The portion of the paper that (e,f) lies in determines which side of the paper remains stationary during the fold. You may assume that this value will always lie on a portion of the square (e.g. not on a part of the square that is not there because of a fold).

For example, the input 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 0.5 means that one should fold the paper in half over the vertical line at 0.5, with the left side remaining stationary.

Each fold (set of input numbers) is sequential, so one fold is made after another.

For example, if the previous example was followed by the input 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, the paper should be folded over the horizontal line at 0.5, with the top part remaining stationary.

### Output

Your program or function must only output (graphically) the resulting shape and rotation of the folding. It is not required to output the correct location or size.

### Test Cases

input 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75 -

[image]

input 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.25, 0.5 -

[image]

input - 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75 -

[image]

input - 0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5

[image]

This is code-golf, so shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: So all folds are valley folds? No mountain folds at all? You could add support for that by adding a command that flips the paper. Also, I don't think your resolution of the folding direction is unambiguous. Which way do I fold a fold that goes from the top left corner to the bottom right corner? And what coordinate system are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, but all of that seems contradictory. If the origin is in the upper left, I assume that the y axis points down. In that case, the fold would be indicated by (0,0) to (1,1). This fold can occur bottom left to top right or vice versa. Your first rule says we should fold right, but the second rule says we should fold down. Therefore, I think this *is* ambiguous.

Comment: Hopefully this is better specified. (BTW, I was confused when you said top left to bottom right. That would have worked left to right/top to bottom. I see what you meant now).

Comment: "*Your program or function must only output the resulting shape and rotation of the folding.*" In what format? Your examples show pictures, but it's not clear whether this is intended to be a [tag:graphical-output] question or whether e.g. a list of vertices is acceptable.

Comment: This challenge proposal has been inactive for over a month. I would like to take ownership of the challenge and make it ready for posting. Please let me know within the next 14 days if you have any objections and would still like to finish and post this challenge yourself.

Comment: Feel free to post it yourself. I have no objections to your ownership. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## Be the shortest in your own standard

This was cops-and-robbers at the beginning. But I'm thinking of changing it to a [user scored challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45040/25180) instead, where each user can propose a limit number of regex, and for each regex, the shortest matched program gets one point.

Working in progress. More details to be added

---

### Task

(To be added.)

### How to answer

In each answer, you should write a program with length n for the above task, and optionally a regex with no more than n/2 bytes.

The regex should consist of only character literals (including escaped ones) and `[...]` `(...)` `?` `*` `+` `|`. You cannot use other features such as specifying number of repetitions or the beginning/ending anchors.

If you choose to include a regex, you should also specify whether programs should be nearly-matched or nearly-unmatched by the regex, defined as following:

- A regex nearly-matches a program, if there is a character C and a subset S of the set of all occurences of C in the program, that when everything in S is replaced by a character C', the program will be matched by the regex.
- A regex nearly-unmatches a program, if for every character C and every subset S of all occurences of C in the program, that when everything in S is replaced by a character C', the program will not be matched by the regex.

If you choose to nearly-match, it must nearly-match your own program in the same answer. And this program must be shorter than any other answer nearly-matched by the regex. The same applies if you choose to nearly-unmatch, where your program must be shorter than anything nearly-unmatched.

The programs and regexes should only use printable ASCII, tabs and newlines.

Each user can write any number of programs, but can write at most 5 regexes at the beginning. You can write one extra regex for each 5 upvotes you get.

### Scoring

For each regex, if one of your program is the first of the shortest of the programs nearly-matched/unmatched by the regex according to the specification, you get 2 points. If the regex is not your own, you get one extra point.

Each of your program can be scored more than one times if they are the shortest for more than one regex.

You should not post an answer that doesn't get any score at the time you post it. But you can leave it there if it loses all the score it had. And you can post an answer that is only the shortest for your own regex.

### Rules about posting and editing answers

You can always edit regexes into an answer, if you are allowed to write more regex. But once a program is the shortest for a regex at the time you post the regex, you can't post another regex that makes this version of the program shortest.

You should not edit a program in a way that it loses scores from some regex. And if you edit, you should keep the version that is paired with a regex in your answer.

Regexes should not be modified after posting for any reason if they are valid.

You should not post programs/regexes that is the same as a previous submission.

Comment: @githubphagocyte It is the program + regexes. I left an `m` there when there was only one regex...

Comment: This doesn't seem to prevent people from just writing the best-golfed program. Bowling doesn't seem to work either (and will be a duplicate of the bowler-golfer fraction war). I'll think about it later... Shouldn't post this when I'm sleepy...

Comment: It seems to me that the two regexes will be one character each, or at worst three characters in total.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can comment out the string matching the regex. The rule about replacing a character literal is to make sure the comment character is always available. But I'm going to abandon this post anyway if I can't find a better winning criterion...

Answer (score 1):

### [Phoneword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword) generator

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Goal

The goal is to write the shortest phoneword generator.

#### Input

As input you get for just a sequence of numbers (0-9). Given via `stdin`.

#### Output

You should write the first 15 possible results to `stdout` bonus points if the output only contains real words. The words need to have the exact same length like the input string.

What if there are less than 15 options?

Then you can just make up words.

#### Phoneword

A phoneword, is a sequence of characters, that is typed with letters in your phone which map to the numbers they display.

How to treat 0 and 1

If the input contains a 0 or a 1, you should treat them as 0 and 1. To make a word with them anyway, you can use leetspeak.

#### Mapping

For the mapping check this picture:

[image: Phonekeypad]

Taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad)

As example I use codegolf itself: `26334653` translates to `CODEGOLF` it also gives many more words, [here is a list](http://www.vanity-rechner.de/cgi-bin/vanity.cgi?number=26334653&anz=anz&quant=200&umw=yes&opt=yes&exist=yes&english=yes).

#### Bonus

You can divide the amount of characters by 2, if your code gives only words which are in listed in the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/). For that you are allowed to use a web api to check them.

Comment: Why is it a [restricted-source]? Are there any characters we cannot use in our code?

Comment: Seems pretty similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/implement-t9-like-functionality). The only difference seems to be that you require full matches.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Because I would like to ban languages that are mode for codegolf, I gonna add this.

Comment: @Knerd That isn't indicated by [restricted-source]; there isn't a tag for that. But why banning golfing languages? That doesn't seem fair to me.

Comment: @Sp3000 I agree, that it is similar, but I still would see a difference in the questions themselves, because a) it needs an exact match and b) the 1 and 0 are valid ;)

Comment: @ProgramFOX I edited it a bit, check under rules. The main reason is, usually golfing languages win a contest, because they are made for that purpose. Which seems unfair for me towards other languages.

Comment: Then what does count as a "golfing language"? If you disallow them, there in my opinion should also be a clear definition of what exactly is disallowed.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I think you are right. I'll go and remove that part.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what the input is, what the output is, what mapping between letters and digits you assume, what you mean by a *word*, or why it isn't a duplicate of the question which Sp3000 mentioned.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I updated it a bit.

Comment: If there are less than 15 possibilities that are allowed by the Oxford dictionary, should the code output only the dictionary-approved possibilities, or make it up to 15 with other possibilities?

Comment: The question as written doesn't specify whether 1 and 0 are valid in the input, and if they are, how they should be treated.

Comment: @githubphagocyte check my edit :)

Comment: I would recommend phrasing `Then you can just make up words` more clearly. I'm guessing you mean that the remainder of the 15 possibilities do not need to use real words?

Comment: To ensure everyone has the same interpretation of the rules, I would recommend clarifying what you mean by leetspeak. Does this mean 1 can be used as L and 0 can be used as O? Or can 1 only be used as i? Or either?

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a Random Boolean Expression

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation)

In this challenge, you generate a random Boolean expression -- and then evaluate it.

### Input

Nothing, or a random seed if your program requires one.

### Output

A random Boolean expression and its value, formatted as a string

```
<expr> = <value>
```

The expression should be generated according to the following BNF grammar:

```
<expr> ::= "0" | "1"
         | "(" <expr> "^" <expr> ")"
         | "(" <expr> "v" <expr> ")"
         | "(" <expr> ">" <expr> ")"
         | "~" <expr>
```

Here, `^` stands for binary AND, `v` for binary OR, `>` for implication, and `~` for NOT. Whitespace is not significant. The correct value for the expression should be self-explanatory. Some correct outputs include

```
0 = 0
~ (~1 ^ 1) = 1
((1v1) ^ ~(0 >(1 ^ ~~~0))) = 0
```

### Detailed Rules

Assuming a perfect random number generator, your program must be able to generate any valid Boolean expression with nonzero probability (discounting whitespace). You must use you language's standard RNG, or one of higher quality.

You can write either a function or a full program, and a function can either return its result or print it to STDOUT. The fewest bytes wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

---

I'd like some input on whether this challenge is essentially similar to either [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/804/random-sentence-generator) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/617/advanced-calculator).

Comment: The intro line talks about evaluating the expression, but none of the rest of the question does, and it seems to me that an approach which builds up the string and the value in parallel would meet spec. In that case, it's not a duplicate of the second question. It's borderline-duplicate of the first one, though. I probably wouldn't vote to close as a dupe, but I wouldn't put money on it staying open.

Answer (score 1):

## Operator, i can't remember my phone number... [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

"Hello? Operator? How do i get my phone to tell me its own number?"

The challenge is to write a quine -- from your cellphone. Not a smartphone with a virtual keyboard, mind you. One of the old phones, where to get a 'c' you have to press 2 three times.

Because programmers are lazy, you want to do it in the least amount of keypresses.

---

A previous challenge ([Calculate cell-phone keypresses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32817/calculate-cell-phone-keypresses)) was to calculate the amount of keypresses it takes to produce a set of characters on a cellphone keyboard.

The challenge there wrote out all the keymappings well, so i'll just quote it here.

> The keymaps are:
>
> ```
> 1:1
> 2:abcABC2
> 3:defDEF3
> 4:ghiGHI4
> 5:jklJKL5
> 6:mnoMNO6
> 7:pqrsPQRS7
> 8:tuvTUV8
> 9:wxyzWXYZ9
> 0:<space><newline>0
> ```
>
> To type `exaMPle TExt 01` , you would press `33 99 2 6666 77777 555 33
>   0 8888 33333 99 8 0 <a 1-sec pause here in real life but we'll ignore
>   it>000 1` for a total of 37 keypresses.
>
> The `*` key brings up a map of special characters:
>
> ```
> .,'?!
> "-()@
> /:_;+
> &%*=<
> >£€$¥
> ¤[]{}
> \~^¡¿
> §#|`
> ```
>
> with the first one (`.`) highlighted. You can move to highlight the
>   required character using rectangular navigation keys and it takes
>   another keypress to select.
>
> So to insert `$`, you would press `*↓↓↓↓→→→<select>` i.e. a total of 9
>   key-presses.

This means, that if you use `a = 3` in your code, that is a (1), space (1), = (8), space (1), 3 (7), for a total of 18, even though it's only 5 bytes.

So as not to rule out languages/entries that use characters outside of this range, you can reach it with *#, insert, special, select, {type the Unicode number of the character}, select* for a total of 5 + Unicode #. I suppose you could use this trick to reduce the number of keypresses via `*`.

### Scoring

Your score is the number of keypresses used to type out the code. There is a Stack Snippet that you can use to calculate. It automatically picks the lower number if you could use either `*` or `#`.

The entry with the lowest score after 2 weeks wins!

Comment: To facilate easy calculating of the score, i plan to include a snippet with the JS entry from the old challenge.

Comment: While I think the scoring *is* a nice twist, I'm not a fan of reusing exactly the same challenge. This way, the scoring seems more like a gimmick than anything else. So I'd prefer if you used it for a different challenge (which may still be related to cellphone keys, just not exactly the same). Also, just a note, please don't actually tag it [tag:code-golf] -  the scoring is too different not to tag it [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: I actually thought of my challenge first, and only after went to see if it had already been asked. But if you think it's too similar, i'll try and think of a slightly different challenge.

Comment: I redid the whole thing, what do you think of it now?

Comment: I have an APL phone where every funny symbol has its own button.

Comment: I like this scoring idea and definitely want to see a challenge based on it, even if it isn't a "quine" challenge.

Comment: For once CJam wouldn't win

Answer (score 1):

## Hide your code in a Boggle board!

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[boggle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boggle)

> This proposal is intended to supersede my earlier proposal [Find the Needle in the Haystack](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2499/8478), of which I'm not convinced any more that it would work very well. I'll keep both proposals around for now, though.

### The Cops' Challenge

First, choose a program output, consisting of less than 100 printable ASCII characters (character code 0x20 to 0x7E, inclusive) - in particular the program must be written on a single line.
Next, you should write a number of programs (not necessarily in the same language), which all output that exact same string (including any trailing newlines) to STDOUT or closest alternative. Each of those programs should be made up of less than 100 printable ASCII characters, too.
Finally, design a Boggle board, which contains all of these programs. The Boggle board may contain as many unused character as you wish, but it has to be rectangular and all characters have to be in the printable ASCII range. See "Boggle Rules" below for how the Boggle board works.

You want the number of programs to be large, the board to be small and the programs to be hard to find.

None of the programs must take any input. You may print to STDOUT, a GUI dialog (as with JavaScript's `alert()`), or assume a REPL environment (like a browser console) - but if it's different from STDOUT, you need to state clearly where your output will go in each case.

Each program has to complete within 5 seconds on a reasonable machine. You are not allowed to use cryptographic methods, hashing functions, random seeds or string compression.

If your submission's boggle board is **X** characters wide, and **Y** characters tall, and you've hidden **N** programs in it, your submission's score is **N<sup>3</sup>/(X*Y)**.

You should deliver:

- **X**, **Y**, **N** and your score.
- The languages of your **N** programs, including output destination if it differs from STDOUT.
- The Boggle board.
- The output of the programs.

An answer is cracked if **N** programs in the specified languages are found by a single robber (see **The Robbers' Challenge** below). If your answer has not been cracked for 7 days, you may claim immunity by revealing the programs in your answer (to prove that your answer was solvable).

The winner will be the *immune* submission with the highest score.

### The Robbers' Challenge

Every user has *one* attempt at cracking each submission. Your cracking attempt will be a list of programs found in a the submission's Boggle board. If your guess matches the description (all programs can be found according to the Boggle rules, all produce the correct output to the correct destination, and they are written in the required languages), and you are the first correct guess, then you get **N*X*Y** points. It is important to note that your programs do *not* have to exactly match the originals, as long as they meet the specification and can be found in the Boggle board. This means there could be more than one correct answer.

The robber with the most points wins. In the case of a tie, the robber who submitted *fewer* cracks wins.

**Robbers should post their cracks as answers to the associated Robbers' thread.**

### Boggle Rules

- To find a program in a Boggle board, you start at an arbitrary cell and add characters to the string by repeatedly moving to one of its neighbours.
- You may move one cell at a time, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.
- No cell must be used more than once (within a single program or by multiple programs).

### Example

Consider this Boggle board as a cop submission:

```
1$int
arun"
!pts0
b "2K
```

Along with the specification that the output is `20`, and that there are 2 CJam programs, one Python 2 program and one Ruby program. A robber could now find:

- `K` in the bottom right corner and `20` next to it as two valid CJam program.
- `print "20"` as a valid Python 2 program:

  ```
  __i__
  _r_n"
  _pt_0
  _ "2_
  ```
- `puts"20"` as a valid Ruby program:

  ```
  _____
  __u_"
  _pts0
  __"2_
  ```

If no one cracked this, the cop's score would be **4<sup>2</sup>/(5*4) = 0.8**. If someone did crack this, that robber would get **4*5*4 = 80** points.

### Sandbox Notes

- I intend to provide stack snippets which generate leaderboards for the cops and robbers.
- The scores probably need some balancing. Suggestions?
- I admit that the robbers' challenge is pretty similar to [Calvin's Hobbies' recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44607/8478). This happened purely by accident - I was originally thinking about a word search C'n'R, which would have been too easily brute-forcible, so I changed it to a Boggle board. Of course, that doesn't matter when considering if it's a duplicate of course, but I think with hand-designed boards, looking for programs with fixed outputs in prescribed languages, makes this quite different and should hopefully make for a [more balanced](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44608/8478) challenge. Furthermore, the cops' challenge of *designing* the boards is completely different. Please let me know if you disagree, though.
- Should I allow cells to be reused within a single program?

Comment: I'd guess that allowing cells to be reused within a single program would make it much harder for a cop to prevent multiple unintended programs appearing in the board.

Comment: I dislike the 'output any 100 printable ASCII characters rule' from the Unscramble challenge. It makes it too easy for cops, who can print out any stream of gibberish. It some languages, it is even possible for them to enter random characters without even knowing what the code does.

Comment: @feersum I'm absolutely open to suggestions for better tasks.

Comment: How about recommend allowing cells to be reused (the whole fun of Boggle), but allowing one program per language?

Comment: @Ypnypn hm, sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

## Logic Dots [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[puzzle-solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-solver) - Posted

Comment: This wants the tag [tag:puzzle-solver]. It isn't clear until really late that the shapes to place are all lines (or `a`  by `1` rectangles, if you prefer): making that clear quite early would be useful. Without that context, the two 2s in the second example look like a requirement to place a 2x2 square. On my first read-through I took "*they can also be vertical*" to mean that some of the input shapes could be vertical: it wasn't until I saw the examples that I could reinterpret it as "You may rotate the shapes when placing them".

Comment: @PeterTaylor fixed.

Comment: Posting test cases as an answer is a bad idea. To shorten the post, you could try putting the examples side by side, and you could use Stack Snippets.

Answer (score 1):

## Find longest alphabet path (code-golf)

You are given a 2d array of size nxn that is filled with lowercasel letters `a-z`. Your goal is to find the longest continous path by only moving up/down/left/right.
A path is a sequence of cells of the 2d grid, where the successor of the current cell must be a neighbour that is above, below, left or right. Also, each cell of the array can only be visited once per sequence. The value (the lowercase letter) of the successor must right before or after the one in the current cell (if the current cell has the value `c`, the successor must have value `b` or `d`).

## Output

You have to solve two tasks:

- The challenge stated above
- The challenge stated above plus another restriction: successors can only have the next letter in the alphabet, but not the previosu (if the current cell has the value `c` the successor must have the value `d`)

The output must consist of two n x n grids the same size as the input, each for one of the two tasks. The grids have to be the identical again, but all the unused cells that are not part of the longest sequence have to be set to a whitespace. If there are two or more longest sequences, only one arbitrary one of them has to be in the output.

## Testcases (more to be added)

```
Input:  Out1:  Out2:     
ababa   ababa  ab         
babab   babab        
ababa   ababa        
babab   babab        
ababa   ababa

Input:  Out:  Out:
aba     aba   ab
aba
aba

abcd  abcd  abcd
hgfe  hgfe  hgfe
gfeb  gfeb  
babc  babc
```

Comment: This looks to me like a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44922/194

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember that challenge, but to me it seems different enough for a new challenge: On the one hand this challenge uses a 2d string instead of 1d on the other hand there is no restriction to words plus another output format needed. I think the overall ideas and needed approaches are quite different. [Inspiration (i do not know what those puzzles are called genearlly)](http://www.worksheetworks.com/english/alphabet/alphabet-maze.html)

Comment: I see it as two versions of the longest path problem on sparse graphs with different graphs.

Comment: Ok if you look at it like this, they are indeed the same problem, but I think the implementation will provide very different challenges.

Answer (score 1):

## Cursor Wars

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This question is based off of my previous [Navigate Text with Arrow Keys](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45515/navigate-text-with-arrow-keys) golf.  Here, a segment of text is the battle arena, and the opponents move like cursors.

### Idea 1: Tron / Light-Bikes

As the cursors move left to right, they paint parts of the text.  Neither cursor can move through a painted area.  The cursor who runs out of moves first loses.

To add a twist to the board's topology, I could make it so that the text area is flipped for the opponent.  If I see the board:

```
X-----
---
------Y
```

Then the opponent sees the board:

```
Y------
---
-----X
```

With line-wrapping working differently for each player, they don't have the same movement patterns.

### Idea 2: Area Painting

Like in the Tron idea, cursors paint an area.  The cursor that paints the most area wins.

I could make it make a few versions

- Area painted once cannot be repainted: the winner is the cursor that painted the majority of area
- Area can painted my moving right and cleared by moving left (backspacing).  The winner is the one that painted the most area times time.  (Each time step, players earn one point per painted area.)

Comment: Idea 3 (rather vague): Put actual characters on the board and have people collect them to form words or sentences (either as the winning criterion or to get some form of power-ups). This could still be based around a Tron idea, or characters could simply be used up (so that others can still travel there, but thy can't collect those characters again).

Answer (score 1):

## War of the Partitions

You have been assigned 1000 men to your cause, and you must fight your opponent on 20 different battlefields simultaneously.  You must decide how to split up your 1000 men into 20 ways.  Furthermore, since the Nth battlefield is larger than the (N+1)th battlefield, the 20 partitions must be in non-increasing order.

Each battlefield will have a skirmish. If you send more men than your opponent, you win that skirmish.  Winning more skirmishes than your opponent across all battlefields scores you 1 Battle Point.

You will then face every other opponent, where you will be allowed to reassign your men to another location.  You have a large supply of necromancers that allow you to keep all of your men alive from battle to battle, so you may allocate all 1000 men every time you face another opponent.

You will face each opponent 25 times.  The player with the most Battle Points wins.

## IO

You will be passed a string of the history of the battles between you and your current opponent.  Each line consists of a different battle.  The choices will be space separated, and your opponent's choices will be listed first, separated by a comma.  The following input:

```
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50,60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50,51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 21
```

would represent two battles between a player.  The first one would be a tie (each player won 10 skirmishes), while the second you won a Battle Point by winning 19 skirmishes.

You must return a string containing a space separated list of integers.  The total of all of the values must be 1000, and must be in decreasing order.

Comment: This game idea sounds very... familiar... but I don't see any KOTH based on it.  Seems like a good idea.

Comment: Maybe change decreasing to non-increasing to prevent ambiguity.

Comment: Will the 25 battles be consecutive? It could be much quicker to save state (if allowed) than re-parse the whole history. (edit: file IO maybe slower, depends on the submissions and time limits)

Comment: @rcrmn the two battling bots are side by side.  The top line is the first battle, the second line is the second battle.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread it!

Answer (score 1):

## Minimum? Vertex Cover

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

```
<insert definition of (minimum) vertex cover here>
```

Given a graph, you must output a *valid* vertex covering of that graph. The entry with the smallest total size (number of vertices) over five test cases (TBD) wins.

#### Input

Your program will be run with one argument given: a file name. For example:

```
python findacover.py graph_1.txt
```

Submissions will read the graph from the file specified. The format of the file will be:

```
5
0:1 2 3
1:0 3
2:0
3:0 1 4
4:3
```

The first line is simply the number of vertices in the graph (V). The next V lines are the list of vertices. Each line consists of the vertex number and a colon, followed by a space-separated list of vertices connected to that vertex by an edge.

Note that each edge will be listed twice, once for each vertex it connects. You can see in the example that the edge connecting `1` and `3` is present on the line for both vertices.

#### Output

Output is simply a list of vertices that represent a valid vertex covering of the input graph. Output should be written to STDOUT (so my validator can score it.

I will strip all non-digit, non-space characters (`[^0-9 ]`) from your output and interpret the remainder as a space-separated list. For example, outputs  `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and `0 1 2 3` will be treated the same.

For the example graph above:

**Valid:**

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
0 3
```

among others.

**Invalid:**

```
0 1 2
```

This does not cover the graph, since the edge between `3` and `4` is not covered.

#### Rules

- Submissions will be run once for each graph.
- You have a time limit of **five minutes** for each graph. You cannot "roll over" unused time to the next graph. This time is clocked on my computer, an [i7-3770K CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/65523/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) with 16GB RAM, running Ubuntu 14.04. If you might bump against this limit, make sure you send a "best-yet" output before time is up.
- Feel free to use multiple threads, but keep it on the CPU. My graphics card is not your playground.
- Your submission must be deterministic. If you use a PRNG, seed it with a constant value.
- You cannot use any built-in or third-party function designed to solve vertex covering problems.
- Standard loopholes apply. This means (for example) that you cannot hardcode your submission to these test cases. If I choose five more test cases to run, you should get comparable (obviously not exact) results.

#### Scoring

Your score is the number of vertices in your cover. If you return anything except a valid covering, or do not return anything within the time allotted, your score for the graph will be 200000.

Score is summed over **five test cases**, each consisting of a graph with 20k to 100k vertices. The lowest total score wins.

```
<link to test cases here>
<insert generator/validator/scorekeeper here>
```

---

#### Sandbox

- Does the "function designed to solve vertex covering problems" need to be better specified? If so, how could I word that?
- Are the graph sizes and time limits reasonable? They are designed to prevent a straight brute-force attack, but I don't believe they are too large to prevent a good approximation. Are they too *small?*

Comment: "Function designed to solve NP-complete problems?" Not sure, but I'm assuming you also want to rule out equivalent things like independent set.

Answer (score 1):

## Code File Header

Do you have a large number of source files that you forgot to put a header on, but never bothered. Well then this challenge is for you!
This is code golf, so shortest program that works wins.

## The Challenge

Write a function (if your language doesn't support this, write a program, that accepts a cmd line arg for the file name) that takes the name of a file then attaches to the top of that file a comments section stating the name of the author, the current date, and the file name, as comments in your language (if your language supports comments, if not then in C-Style/Doxygen).

For instance, if your language was `C/C++` the following must be appended at the top.
using myself as the example.

```
/** \author Henry Schmale
 * \date 2015-02-19
 * \file [File Name]
 */
```

## Notes

- You may subtract the length of your name from your submission.
- Languages that don't support file I/O are not eligible for this code golf.
- The date code should be in a human readable format, no unix time. Preferably in ISO format.
- if your language supports multiple comment formats, you may use either or so long as the final result is the same, a documentation header on that file.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I did this before I learned how to use doxygen.

Comment: What file name should be used if reading from stdin and writing to stdout?

Comment: The spec regarding the file name is a bit confusing now. First you say "Write a function [...] that takes the name of a file then attaches to the top of that file [...] the file name" but then you say "Assume the file name is `main.c`". I think a simpler option would be to *always* take the file name as a command-line or function argument, but allow people to choose between STDIN/STDOUT, file I/O and another function parameter/return value for the actual file contents.

Comment: So why did you go back to disallowing languages without file system support now? :/

Answer (score 1):

*I'm only posting this in the sandbox because it may be too broad, even for a pop-con. If it gets some support I'll post it very soon.*

## Generating Postmodernist Writing and Other Logorrhea

[Postmodernist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism) writings are known for dealing with highly abstract ideas, potentially in a [verbose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbosity) manner that may sound nonsensical to someone reading them. This type of writing is often called *logorrhea*, and is not limited to postmodernism.

People have made programs that use [natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) to generate realistic looking academic writings that are actually utter nonsense.
One example is the [Postmodernism Generator](http://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism_Generator)), which creates a random postmodernist essay every time the page is loaded. Another example is [SCIgen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCIgen#Spoofing_Google_Scholar_and_h-index_calculators)), which can generate random papers about computer science.

Your task in this popularity contest is to write a program that can generate random, convincing paragraphs of academic logorrhea. You can choose what topic your program will generate text about. Postmodernism, CS, math, physics, and philosophy seem to be likely choices, but you can choose something else.

- Your program must be able to take in a 32 bit integer (a value from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1) as a seed value and output a random paragraph of text on your topic. None of the 2<sup>32</sup> outputs should be identical. (If desired, you can include an option for no input, where the seed number is just chosen randomly.)
- The paragraphs should be from 2 to 8 sentences long and between 300 and 1000 characters. The sentences should start with capitals and end with periods. Including other punctuation is optional.
- The actual content of the sentences **does not need to make grammatical sense**, though it should consist of real English words. Presumably, the more it does make sense the more it will be upvoted.
- You do not need to include author names or citations like the [Postmodernism Generator](http://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/) does. You could though, and you are welcome to take some liberties and generate a full essay or a mini-paper or something if it's clear that what you're doing is more difficult that just generating a paragraph.
- You may use any [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) libraries or resources, provided they don't already automatically generate random academic text. e.g. taking a paragraph from a random [SCIgen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) paper would not be allowed at all.

The highest voted answer wins.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be narrowed down to a specific topic/area. How about homeopathy?

Comment: @trichoplax: Randomly generated articles on homeopathy might end up getting published. ;)

Comment: @AlexA. that would be priceless :)  The winning condition could be the number of homeopathy journals it gets published in.

Answer (score 1):

## [Find the maximum of ax+b](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47539/25180)

## Find the maximum of ax+b online

You are given a list of (*a,b*), and a list of *x*. Compute the maximum *ax+b* for each *x*. You can assume *a*, *b* and *x* are non-negative integers.

But this time, items in the list are added dynamically. Your program should support the following operations (you can rename the operations if that's convenient):

- `Add a,b`, to insert (*a,b*) into the list.
- `Query x`, to find the maximum *ax+b* in the current list, with the given *x*.

Your program or function must run in expected (to the randomness if your code involves that, not the input) **O(*nlogn*) time** where *n* is the total input length (or total number of operations).

You can write a complete program, a function, a list of functions or methods doing each operation, or a function taking one operation each time. For the later two cases, you can either return or print the result after each operation, or add an "output" operation, or output automatically when the program ends.

#### Examples

(will be added later.)

This is code-golf. Shortest code wins.

#### Note about the complexity:

If you used a builtin having a good average-case complexity, and it can be randomized to get the expected complexity easily in theory, you can assume your language did that.

That means, if your program can be tested to be O(*nlogn*) (in theory), with edge cases for your code, but not the implementation of your language, we'll say it is O(*nlogn*).

Comment: Can we assume our language's built-in sorting is O(n lg n)?

Comment: @xnor Usually they are O(n lg n). But if you meant some language with a built-in sorting function not in O(n lg n) (or nobody is bothered to check the real complexity), I'm not sure. Strictly speaking they may be not in O(n lg n) and invalid. But it seems nobody is downvoting or deleting those answers.

Comment: @user23013 They are very rarely O(n log n). Most languages implement quick sort, which is O(n log n) on average but has a worst case complexity of O(n^2). That being said, I'd always include a statement along the lines "you may assume that your language's built-in sorting function runs in O(n log n)".

Comment: @MartinBüttner Allowed expected complexity. Is it better now?

Comment: I don't know... it just seems unnecessarily complicated to me and puts some esolangs at a disadvantage that might have a naive sort implementation, but ultimately it's your call.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Do you have ideas about the stronger version (allowing inserting (a,b) dynamically)? I'm trying to make it consistent. And esolangs can answer the convex hull question anyway.

Comment: @user23013 I don't think I'm qualified to have an opinion about the stronger version. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Which Children Don't Play Well Together? [code-<s>golf</s>challenge]

You are a kindergarten teacher who is having problems with fights breaking out among the students. You have noticed that altercations happen only when certain groups of children are together. A group of children who can't play well together, but will coexist peacefully if any one student is removed from the group, is known as a MIKG (minimal incompatible kindergartener group). Every MIKG contains at least two children. To help prevent problems, you decide to identify all such groups of kindergarteners.

Each day, your class has Group Reading Time. This involves dividing the children into groups of 1 or more students, who take turns reading pages from a picture book. If all the children from an MIKG are placed in the same reading group, a commotion will erupt. The distraction rapidly involves all the students in the class, so you can't tell which reading group it originated from.

You want to find all the MIKGs as soon as possible, so you write a computer program to help you do the math. Let f(N) be the maximum number of days it will take to identify all the MIKGs in a class of size N, assuming an optimal strategy is used. The program should not take more than f(N) days to find the answer.

### Input/Output

At the beginning of the program, it takes a positive integer input of N which tells the number of students in the class. Then, the program creates a plan for the day's reading groups. The user (kindergarten teacher) will input 1 if a disruption occurred during reading time, or a 0 if it remained calm.
When the program determines all the MIKGs, it shall print them out and exit.

### Challenge

You will be given random test cases for class sizes between (a) and (b). The goal is to determine the MIKGs in as few days as possible. The program that makes the smallest amount of queries is the winner, with tiebreak by earliest post.

### Restrictions

- The program must respond in under (x) seconds
- Due to the interactivity requirement, you must submit a full program, not a function.
- You may specify any format for the I/O as long as it is clear, unambiguous, consistent, and doesn't use characters other than printable ASCII and newlines.

### Sandbox notes

- TODO: add examples
- A formula in terms of [Dedekind numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) M(n) for the number of possibilities:
  [image]
- TODO: fix formula
- TODO: create random test case generator
- using http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_4/PDF/v4i2r15.pdf (?)

Comment: I presume that an MIKG must contain at least two children, but it would be good to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

## Musical Blinkenlights

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [hardware](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

---

## Introduction

If you take a look at the front panel of your desktop or laptop computer, chances are that you'll find a handful of [blinkenlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights), including a hard disk activity indicator.

[image: HDD blinkenlight turning on and off]
<sup>Image taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/456360/getting-laptop-wireless-led-to-indicate-wireless-network-activity)</sup>

The idea of this challenge is to "play" the [Shave and a Haircut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shave_and_a_Haircut) melody with that light.

## The Task

Your task is to write a full program with the following behavior.
If the program is placed in an empty directory, compiled (if applicable) and run, it causes the hard drive activity light to blink the notes of the Shave and a Haircut melody (unless, of course, the hard drive is active for some other reason).
After that, it shall exit gracefully.

## Precise Rules

The specification of the melody is as follows.
Let `t` be a unit of time between 0.2 seconds and 0.7 seconds.
Starting from some time `tinit`, the activity light shall blink at `tinit`, `tinit + t`, `tinit + 1.5*t`, `tinit + 2*t`, `tinit + 3*t`, `tinit + 5*t`, and `tinit + 6*t`.
The blink must be long enough to be noticed by the human eye, but no more than `0.25*t`.

Your program may create and modify any files and subdirectories in the directory it is placed in, including its own source code.
The program does not have to be cross-platform, but you must state your operating system in your answer, and any necessary hardware requirements.
In particular, some environments allow the blinkenlights to be controlled manually; this is perfectly acceptable, but must be explicitly stated.

**Your program may not damage or significantly alter the host computer.**

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the lowest byte count wins.
Standard loopholes are disallowed.

---

### Sandbox Notes

My main concern is whether my challenge would be too similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33059/draw-with-your-cpu).

Comment: This seems somewhat hard to test. The hard drive activity in response to a given file access sequence could depend on the model of drive, the filesystem, and any number of filesystem or OS config options. I don't think it's reasonable to expect anyone to be able to state the hardware and config requirements.

Comment: Musical nitpick: what you want is the Shave and a Haircut *rhythm* not melody. I thought you were asking something more difficult (especially as I didn't know that jingle was called that.) I like the challenge though.

Comment: I think this might have a problem - lots of processes go on at all times in a computer. It would be hard to predict when the light just blinks randomly, and you couldn't shut those processes down (i.e, `compiz` on Linux). Plus, how would the challenge be verified, and what if it was only qualified/disqualified because of a random blink?

Answer (score 1):

## It's just a flesh wound!

The idea is to create a program that:

- If any one of the four quarters (counted in bytes) is removed, the program outputs "Tis' but a scratch" (exactly, with optional newline).
- If any two of the four quarters are removed, the program outputs "Just a flesh wound.".
- If any three of the four quarters are removed, the program outputs "Let's call it a draw, then.".
- The full program should output "None shall pass.".

Rules:

- The program has to have length divisible by four (4).
- The program must not read it's own source or it's length in any way.
- The output is to stdout if it is possible in your language (REPL output is considered valid in this case).
- The answer with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I don't think this would actually be a duplicate of anything in the [tag:source-layout] tag, but it doesn't feel like it would add anything to the sum of what's already in that tag.

Comment: Would these 'quarters' be defined by the user, or is it any random 1/4th of the program?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI The quarters are successive quarters of the code. ie. the first one is 0 - 1/4, second is 1/4 - 2/4, third is 2/4 - 3/4 and fourth is 3/4 - 4/4

Comment: Would it be allowed to read the program's own length?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI No. Updated.

Comment: Here's an idea: If it is full, it prints `None shall pass.`, one-quarter, `Tis' but a scratch.`, and three-quarters, `Let's call it a draw, then.`.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

## Fortnightly Challenge #8: A new kind of "asynchronous" KOTH

This is a placeholder for the challenge spec.  You can discuss this challenge in [a special chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22138/fortnightly-challenge-of-2015-03-20-asynchronous-koth).

---

Ordinary KOTHs require that a single user take up the job of hosting the competition: running the whole competition at once by themselves. Everything is dependent on them, and they can only run so many competitions or update ever so frequently. I think this can be improved... somehow.

Here are some ideas, many of which would require an encryption scheme or something to ensure correctness.

- Anybody can run the tournament and add their results to the current leaderboard somehow. This could be accomplished by some sort of cryptographic scheme to verify the results. Ideally the controller will be implemented via stack snippet to allow ordinary people to run it without downloading a controller.
- When a bot is added/updated, only the new pairs of contestants should be tried, and nearly anyone can update the leaderboard by themselves. (Assuming a deterministic KOTH, which it will probably need to be in order to prevent people from simply uploading the results that occurred in their favor.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading this forum for a bit and I thought it might be a good idea to do a short sequence of challenges themed on famous mathematicians. It's my first post here so please point out any shortcomings.

It is Irving Kaplansky's birthday today. Among other things he is famous for his [conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky%27s_conjecture) on [group rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring). It is one of these conjectures in mathematics that requires virtually no special knowledge to understand. There a couple of words that need explaining in them but their definitions are very simple. These words are "[group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29)",  "[torsion-free group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_%28algebra%29)", "[ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29)", "[domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_%28ring_theory%29)", "[group ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring)", "[idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)", "[unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29)".

Please read up if you want to. This challenge doesn't require understanding these words or the conjecture. All that's needed is the concept of a finite cyclic group. I'm sure most of you know what it is, but I'll give a short introduction. A cyclic group of order n can be understood as what you get when you take something (whatever) called a generator, say p, and decide that it can be raised to integer powers. These powers can be multiplied like so: p<sup>k</sup> * p<sup>l</sup> = p<sup>k+l</sup>. But there's one catch: whenever the exponents of the powers give the same remainder from the division by n, these powers are considered equal. This means, in particular, that there are exactly n powers really: p<sup>0</sup>, p<sup>1</sup>,...,p<sup>n-1</sup>. Any other power is equal to one of these.

The challenge is to implement a certain operation on certain formal expressions involving these powers. The expressions are of this form:

> r<sub>0</sub> * p<sup>0</sup> + r<sub>1</sub> * p<sup>1</sup> + ... + r<sub>n-1</sub> * p<sup>n-1</sup>,

where all r<sub>i</sub> are real numbers.

The operation, called multiplication, consists in, first, multplying two such expressions as if they were real sums, that is for example, for n=3:

> (2 * p<sup>0</sup> + 3 * p<sup>1</sup> + 2 * p<sup>2</sup>) * (0 * p<sup>0</sup> + 1 * p<sup>1</sup> + 2 * p<sup>2</sup>)=
>
> (2 * p<sup>0</sup>) * (0 * p<sup>0</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>0</sup>) * (1 * p<sup>1</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>0</sup>) * (2 * p<sup>2</sup>) +
>
> (3 * p<sup>1</sup>) * (0 * p<sup>0</sup>) + (3 * p<sup>1</sup>) * (1 * p<sup>1</sup>) + (3 * p<sup>1</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>2</sup>) +
>
> (2 * p<sup>2</sup>) * (0 * p<sup>0</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>2</sup>) * (1 * p<sup>1</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>2</sup>) + (2 * p<sup>2</sup>).

Then, we simplify each of the summands according to the rule

> (r * p<sup>k</sup>) * (s * p<sup>l</sup>) = (r * s) * (p<sup>k</sup> * p<sup>l</sup>) = (r * s) * p<sup>k+l</sup>.

And finally, we simplify the resulting sum according to the rule

> (r * p<sup>k</sup>) + (s * p<sup>k</sup>) = (r + s) * p<sup>k</sup>.

This means that for n=3, we have 2 * p<sup>2</sup> + 5 * p<sup>5</sup> = 7 * p<sup>2</sup> because p<sup>2</sup>=p<sup>5</sup>!

The resulting sum is again of the form

> r<sub>0</sub> * p<sup>0</sup>+ r<sub>1</sub> * p<sup>1</sup> + ... + r<sub>n-1</sub> * p<sup>n-1</sup>

after we order the summands by the exponents.

This operation is exactly the product in the group ring R[C], where R is the field of real numbers and C is a finite cyclic group. This group ring doesn't satisfy the hypothesis of Kaplansky's conjecture because finite cyclic groups aren't torsion-free.

Your task is to implement this in any language. Your program/procedure/whatever has to take a natural number n>0 as user input. This will be the order of your cyclic group. Then it has to take 2n "real numbers" as user input. I don't really care what the "real numbers" are in your implementation. They could be ints for all I care. Just make them something that can reasonably be interpreted as real numbers and has a reasonable arithmetic. The first n numbers will be the coefficients of the first formal sum and the other n numbers will be the coefficients of the second formal sum. You need to output the n coefficients of their product. You don't need to compute the product in the way describe above. It just has to be correct (modulo rounding errors and other things computers do wrong with numbers).

Shortest code wins. You can assume the input is valid. Both input and output can be in any reasonable form. I'm not sure if this is a good restriction on this site, but I'd like you to think "actually usable". Though I don't really care about how long it takes to compute. I guess all standard loopholes apply, as I've noticed it seems to be a mantra here. :-)

As I said, please help me improve this challenge and oh, feel free to edit.

Comment: Did you mean to shift the indices in "r_1 * p^0 + r_2 * p^1 + ... + r_(n-1) * p^(n-1)"? Also, do I understand right that you're asking for us to multiply formal polynomials under the relation`x^n = 1`?

Comment: @xnor I didn't mean to do that! And yes, that's one way of saying this. Another way of saying it is to multiply elements of the group ring R[C] where C is a finite cyclic group and R is the field of real numbers. My goal is to introduce the concept of a group ring and this is one of the simplest cases. For the infinite cyclic group it would amount to the Laurent polynomials, and that's too familiar I think. This is the next simplest case.

Comment: @Martin Done, thanks!

Comment: @xnor I've corrected the indices (there were some more errors). Do you think this is too simple? I was thinking of doing it with the quaternion group...

Comment: Added the statement that this is a group ring product.

Comment: I think the problem is OK, but people might just do this by multiplying regular polynomials and then combining `x^(n+i)` with `x^i`. I like the group idea, but I've already [done the quaternions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36928/20260).

Comment: @xnor Well, for the quaternions it wouldn't be as simple. Perhaps I could stipulate that one of the answers to your problem should be used in some way?

Comment: What do you mean that it wouldn't be as simple?

Comment: @xnor I mean that it wouldn't be just a simple variation on polynomial multiplication. It's still similar because that's what the (semi)group ring multiplication is: a generalization of polynomial multiplication. But the case of the quaternion group is further away from polynomials than cyclic groups.

Answer (score 1):

## Functioning HTML-Encoded Program

---

**Introduction**

When showing code to others on the web, some characters are generally replaced by their HTML-encoded entities. Browsers display this properly, but if a user copies the code directly from HTML or a script tries running the code without decoding its entities, the code will likely contain errors.

**Challenge**

You are to come up with a program that uses all of the following five characters: `"`, `&`, `'`, `<`, and `>`. When encoded to their named XHTML entities, the code must still run using the following respective entities: `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The code must be able to run both ways without throwing errors. Each of the five characters must be used outside of comments and string-like objects at least once (ie. for JS, outside of literal regex). You may use an expression in place of a statement up to one time (if your language supports it).

**Example JS Script (1/5 required characters)**

> **Unencoded:** (Sets `lt` to `true`)
>
> ```
> var lt = 6;
> lt = 3 < lt;
> ```
>
> **Encoded:** (Sets `lt` to `2`)
>
> ```
> var lt = 6;
> lt = 3 &lt; lt;
> ```

**Encoder/Decoder**

Here's a converter to make testing your code easy (click run code to use):

```js
function encode() {
  document.getElementById('post').value = document.getElementById('pre').value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
  if (entity=document.getElementById('pre').value.match(/&\S+?;/)) alert('Warning: Unencoded text may already have entities. (ie: ' + entity[0] + ')');
} function decode() {
  document.getElementById('pre').value = document.getElementById('post').value.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, '\'').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
  if (entity=document.getElementById('post').value.match(/&(?:[\s;]|[^\s;]*(?:\s|$))|<|>|'|"/)) alert('Warning: Encoded text may contain unencoded characters. (ie: ' + entity[0][0] + ')');
}
```

```html
<label for="pre"><b>Unencoded:</b></label> <button onclick="encode()">Encode</button><br /><textarea id="pre" style="width:100%;min-height:49px;resize:vertical"></textarea><br /><br />
<label for="post"><b>Encoded:</b></label> <button onclick="decode()">Decode</button><br /><textarea id="post" style="width:100%;min-height:49px;resize:vertical"></textarea>
```

The shortest functioning unencoded code block wins. Have fun!

Comment: I would vote to close this as too broad, because as far as I can tell from the question, all the program has to do is not crash. It probably wouldn't be a good question even with a spec which required it to perform a stated task, though, because it's so easy to bypass the intent by using no-ops.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That was the point of me including "You may use an expression in place of a statement up to one time (if your language supports it)," but I suppose that I can't assume that'll cover every case of no-ops in programming languages out there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a puzzle to be split into two questions:

## Build an evil-defying Tetris AI

Build a program that takes the state of a current board and a piece and attempts to find the optimal space for it.

Your program will be scored by the number of points it can score against the evil Tetris block generators in the question below. Highest score wins. (scoring algorithm to come later)

## Build an evil Tetris block generator

Build a program that attempts to take the state of a current board and generate the worst possible piece for it.

Your program will be scored by the total number of points the AIs built in the question above can score against it. Lowest score wins.

Comment: In general, if you mainly flood with S and Z then it's basically unsolveable. Also [related](http://qntm.org/files/hatetris/hatetris.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

## Programming Tetris Blocks ([Even More Literally?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48739/programming-tetris-blocks-literally))

In this challenge, you will write a Tetris AI.  There's one twist though: the AI will operate from the perspective of the Tetris blocks themselves.

*Note: I am worried about the novelty of this question.  The key is "the perspective of the Tetris blocks themselves." In order to make this interesting, I have to give the AI a bare minimum of information needed to make a move.  Otherwise, it will just be a regular Tetris AI challenge.*

When a Tetris block is spawned at the top of the map, a new AI object is created.  Each time step, and the block receives data about its immediate surroundings and returns a move (move left/right, rotate clockwise/counterclockwise, or nothing).

An idea as to "block vision": each of the four squares in a block each have four "eyes," one on each side.  Each eye returns the distance to the nearest wall/block (including/excluding other squares in the same block?).  This means that the AI will receive exactly sixteen numbers each update.

```
#######
# 1234#
#  #  #
#### ##
#######
```

If a 2D array where each row (1st level) is a square and each column (second level) is an eye in the directions [U,D,L,R], then here is what could be seen as input, with 0s representing an adjoining block.

```
[[1,2,2,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,3,0,0],[1,2,0,1]]
```

More details coming sometime not now.

Comment: For 'block vision', what if returns -1 if it hits the same block? Also, shouldn't the squares be numbered left to right and up to down, so the I piece is  `[1][2][3][4]`, and an example 'block vision' would be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2]`?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI In your example, which numbers refer to which squares/eyes?

Comment: Square 1 is the first 4 numbers (`[1, 2, 3, 1]`), square 2 the next 4 (`[2, 3, 1, 2]`), etc. The directions are in the format `[U, D, L, R]`, and it works like `[U, D, L, R, U, D, L, R, U, D, L, R, U, D, L, R]`.

Comment: I couldn't really visualize where you were getting the numbers from, so I added my own example.

Answer (score 1):

## KotHgress

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

As everyone knows, the only way to make sure your voice is heard among a group of people is to shout louder than everyone else. This is especially true in KotHgress, a bureaucratic committee of PPCG bots.

The **KotHgress Register** is a 1D string, at least 100 characters long, containing the minutes of each committee meeting. The only problem is that all the committee members talk at the same time, often shouting over each other, so that (like a typical committee), nothing ever gets done. However, since this is a committee of bots, efficiency is prized almost as much as volume.

## Rules

The Register for each meeting is a string of length `max(100, N_bot * 4)`. At the beginning of each meeting, a committee member bot is pseudorandomly assigned an ascii character to be its voice, and 3 starting positions for its voice in the Register (initial index of 1), with each bot's positions having the same sum - for example, [1,4,100] and [5, 25, 75] could be starting positions.

Each turn, a bot receives 20 points times the number of times its voice appears in the Register. The bot can spend any amount of its points to bid on positions in which to place its voice. A bot that does not spend all its points banks any remaining points towards its score for the round; points do not carry over to following rounds.

Once all bids have been collected, each position is overwritten with the voice of the highest bidder, with ties for high bid causing no change in that position's current character. **Note: a bot that is outbid for a position it already occupies loses that position.**

Then, each bot accumulates score equal to the combined rank of its voice characters in the Register (for example, `"ABABB"` would score 4 for `"A"` at rank 1 and 3, and 11 for `"B"` at rank 2, 4, and 5), and the Register is sent as input to each member for them to choose their next bids.

After 100 turns, the meeting is over, and the bot with the highest accumulated score wins the meeting.

## Input

Each turn, bot will receive four inputs, in this order:

1. a single character which is its voice
2. a positive integer indicating its current (banked) score
3. a positive integer indicating the number of points it collected this turn
4. a string of length `max(100, N_bot * 4)`, the Register

## Output

The bot should output a string consisting of integer pairs, separated like so: `"pos0 bid0|pos1 bid1|...|posM bidM"`. Banked points will be automatically calculated from the output: `banked_points = turn_points - sum(bids)`.

Invalid output, including `sum(bids) > turn_points`, will cause your bot to lose its turn (not banking any points).

## Meta-notes

- Controller construction is in progress.
- I expect it to be language-agnostic (using a similar setup to aBOTcalypse). Bots will be allowed one storage file for memory purposes.

Comment: I understand that `a > z`, `A > a`, and `A > Z`. But which would be greater: `a` or `Z`? And is the bot with voice `a` placed before or after the bot with voice `b`?

Comment: I was figuring on going in ascii order, so `A->Z->a->z'. That allows for 52 committee members; I can do non-alphas if we get more interest than that, lol.

Comment: OK. Just make sure that you add that to the rules. You could also use some of ASCII's 95 printable characters (minus space, and maybe take out some others that could mess up the input.)

Comment: I'll be a little more specific about this, sure.

Comment: This has the classic KotH flaw: the best strategy is either to be purely random or to be the last person to submit your bot, and to metagame it against everyone else's bots.

Comment: how would one metagame? the priority order is randomized at the beginning of each meeting

Answer (score 1):

## Traffic Troubles

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Background

Consider the following grid:

```
    a   b   c
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
d---+---+---+---e
    |1  |2  |3
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
f---+---+---+---g
    |4  |5  |6
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
h---+---+---+---i
    |7  |8  |9
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
    j   k   l
```

I've marked every endpoint with a letter `a-l`, and every `+` with a number `1-9`. Imagine, for a moment, that this grid represents a small section of a town. Each `|` or `-` represents one segment of a two-way road, and each `+` represents an intersection, which will have a corresponding stoplight.

During the game, cars will be added and removed from the grid at the endpoints `a-l`. Cars move exactly one space (through one segment of road or through one intersection) per turn, and never change direction. Thus, if a car enters the grid at endpoint `d`, it will exit after reaching endpoint `e`. We may assume that the cars are smart enough to avoid all collisions. They will never move to a space occupied by another vehicle, and they will never enter an intersection when the stoplight they see is red. When a car reaches the opposite endpoint, it disappears and can be safely forgotten.

Assume that we have a variable entitled `public_unhappiness` that is initialized to `0`.

If a car following the above rules may not move due to another vehicle or a stoplight, the value of `public_unhappiness` is increased by 1.

*//SANDBOX NOTE: This formula is linear, but one could say that unhappiness goes up exponentially the longer you sit at a stoplight. This formula is subject to change.*

We pit two bots against each other, both controlling traffic flow in different ways. One bot aims to maximize `public_unhappiness` and the other aims to minimize it. We will refer to the former as *The Driver* and the latter as *The Traffic Engineer*. Because this KotH is inherently unbalanced, Drivers and Traffic Engineers will face off in a [round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) tournament (playing only against the opposing faction) and will be placed in separate leaderboards.

## Input

Though the bots are different and rely on entirely different strategies, **every bot has access to the same information**. Every turn, the bots will be prompted with a list of command-line arguments. Below is a general format:

```
./Traffic_Troubles Your_bot.extension S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 N a,b,c a,b,c ...
```

`S1` through `S9` are **binary digits** that represent what direction traffic may flow through the corresponding stoplight. If the value is `1`, traffic flows horizontally through this stoplight. If the value is `0`, traffic flows vertically. Hence, a car approaching intersection `1` from the east will stop moving if the value of `S1` is a `0`, and continue moving along if that value is a `1`.

The following argument is `N`. This represents the number of cars currently active on the board.

There then follows `N` descriptions of cars in the form `a,b,c`. Here, `a` is the character of the endpoint that a car originated, `b` is its destination, and `c` is the number of spaces it has moved. A car that has just been put on endpoint `a` has moved `0` spaces, and would thusly be described as `a,j,0`. On the other hand, a car approaching intersection `6` from the west would be described as `f,g,11`.

On the first turn, every stoplight has value `0`, and no cars exist on the board (`N == 0`).

*//SANDBOX NOTE: This input seems pretty messy... Any ideas?*

## The Traffic Engineer

Traffic Engineers aim to minimize `public_unhappiness` by changing the values of the stoplights to allow for traffic to continue through.

You may specify the values of up to three stoplights per turn. Every turn your bot is called, you must provide up to `3` space-separated output pairs of the form `a,b` where `a` is the number of the spotlight you want to change, and `b` will be a **binary digit** representing the desired value of the stoplight. Invalid output will count as a change to the stoplights, but be ignored. You may choose to output any number of changes less than or equal to 3.

*//SANDBOX NOTE: The value of 3 is subject to change.*

## The Driver

Drivers aim to maximize `public_unhappiness` by choosing entry points for cars.

Every turn, you may output up to six distinct entry points for cars in the form `X Y Z ...`. If a car already exists on that entry point *and is not moving in the opposite direction* that output will be ignored. You may specify any number of entry points less than or equal to 6.

*//SANDBOX NOTE: The number 6 is subject to change*

## The Sequence of Events

1. Both bots are called at roughly the same time with access to the exact same information.
2. Cars are added to the entry points and the value of stoplights are changed.
3. Cars move, and `public_unhappiness` is incremented accordingly.
4. Any car that has surpassed its respective exit point is removed from play.

*//SANDBOX NOTE: Perhaps the Traffic Engineer should be able to view where the Driver put cars and adjust accordingly. Thoughts?*

## Rules

1. Your bot is given 1 second to respond.
2. You may not tailor your bot to act specifically against another bot.
3. Please provide a method for compiling your bot and a command-line method for running your bot.
4. The header of your answer should be in this format:

   `[Language-name] - [Traffic Engineer/Driver] - [Bot-name]`
5. [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

*//SANDBOX NOTE: If this idea is received well (~4-6 upvotes on the sandbox) I will build the controller. For now, it's just an idea. If you wish to run/improve on this KotH, you are welcome to.*

Answer (score 1):

## 8-FTU - Retrofit UTF-8 to any pre-1988 language

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The design of Unicode started in 1987 and was first published in 1988. UTF-8 itself was designed in 1992 and first presented in 1993. Your goal is to retrofit the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode to any language that was in existence on 31 December 1987. You can't use any features that were added to the language after this date.

Your program will take a text input (byte encoded characters, possibly with errors) and up to two integers. Your program must accept any value at any byte position (`00`-`FF`).

#### Task 1 - Validate the input

Your program will print one of `TRUE`/`FALSE`, `True`/`False` or `true`/`false` depending on whether the text is valid UTF-8 or not, and exit if the format is not valid. See below for validation rules. There are also many online resources that cover the format that you can reference.

#### Task 2 - Count the code points

If your program didn't exit at the end of Task 1, it will print the number of Unicode code points encoded within the text.

#### Task 3 - Substring

Using the two integer inputs your program will find and output the matching substring. The first integer will be the starting position, `0` will be the start of the string. If the starting position is after the end of the string, return an empty string. The second integer will be the length of the substring in Unicode code points. If the length is omitted or goes past the end of the string return all the text from the start position to the end of the string. You do not need to program for negative numbers, although you can if you want to.

Tasks 1 & 2 must be printed to standard output.
If printing the output of Task 3 would have undesirable consequences (e.g. characters interpreted as control codes) you may return the text instead. You don't have to worry about how the text will display, your code will be taken by DeLorean or TARDIS (depending on country) to 1987 or earlier where a team of engineers will work on displaying it correctly!

#### Valid encodings

```
  Code points        Byte encoding
---------------    -----------------
U+0000 - U+007F    Standard 7-bit ASCII (00 - 7F)
U+0080 - U+07FF    Two bytes per code point (C2 80 - DF BF)
U+0800 - U+D7FF    Three bytes per code point (E0 A0 00 - ED 9F BF)
U+D800 - U+DFFF    High and low surrogate pairs, invalid in UTF-8 (ED A0 80 - ED BF BF)
U+E000 - U+FFFF    Three bytes per code point (EE 80 80 - EF BF BF)
U+010000 - U+10FFFF    Four bytes per code point (F0 80 80 80 - F4 8F BF BF)
```

#### Byte table

- **00 - 7F**:    Standard 7-bit ASCII
- **80 - BF**:    Continuation bytes
- **C0 - C1**:    Invalid - Task 1 must print one of the false messages if either of these bytes are present
- **C2 - DF**:    Start of two-byte code
- **E0 - EF**:    Start of three-byte code. `ED` codes where the next byte is one of  `A0`-`BF` are invalid because they encode surrogate pairs
- **F0 - F4**:    Start of four-byte code. Note: not all sequences starting with F4 are valid. You need to test for these too
- **F5 - FF**:    Invalid - Task 1 must print one of the false messages if any of these bytes are present

The remainder of a multi-byte code must only be continuation bytes until the length is reached. E.g. `E4 85 B9` is valid because `E4` marks the start of a three byte code, there are exactly three bytes and `85` and `B9` are both within the range `80`-`BF`. A continuation byte must not appear except as part of a multi-byte sequence, which must start with `C2`-`F4`. Long encodings are not allowed. E.g. "A" is `41`, which could also be encoded as `C1 81` or `E0 81 81`. These longer sequences are invalid because there is a shorter, valid sequence.

You don't need to worry about the BOM code point `U+FEFF` (`EF BB BF`). Treat it as any other character even if it appears within the text.

#### Example input (to be expanded)

`C3 87 61 20 76 61 3F` 0 2 (`Ça va?`, 7 bytes, 6 code points)

Outputs:

```
True
6
Ça
```

`C3 87 61 20 76 61 3F` 2 (`Ça va?`, 7 bytes, 6 code points)

Outputs:

```
True
6
 va?
```

`C1 87 61 20 76 61 3F` 0 2 (`Ga va?`, 7 bytes (overlong error), 6 code points)

Outputs:

```
False
```

As mentioned above, the output for Task 3 may be returned as a string instead of printing it.

#### Scoring

Either shortest code in bytes or a bonus awarded for retrofitting an older language. Maybe bytes minus the number of months before January 1988, assuming a release date of December if not otherwise specified?

Answer (score 1):

## Time Travel in KotH

This is not a question but a possible mechanic for KotH ([king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)type challenge).

In KotH we can ask each program (player) to store all its memory in a file between steps. This makes it possible to change a player's memory to an older one which is not possible with human players. This fact makes it possible to crate time-traveling based games.

I will outline to mechanics here, a simpler one (Time Reverters) and a more complex one (Time Travelers). Both will use a simple game to show how they would work.

## Time Reverters (mechanic I)

### A very simple example game

- Two players, `N` rounds.
- At every round a random player scores a point.
- The winner is the player with more points after round `N`.

### The time reverse twist

- At any time in the game a player can chose to time travel (TT) back to any previous round. This means the players will receive the memory they had at that round and forget everything else. Neither of them will know a TT happened.
- Each player can TT `K` times and this is counted by the controller. If a player tries to travel when it has no more travels left, the TT request is simply ignored.

## Time Travellers (mechanic II)

(will be written later...)

Answer (score 1):

## Split multi-language no-space sentences

You will be given a string representing a sentence without word any boundaries. Additionally, you're given a dictionary of all possible words. Output all possible possible ways of splitting the sentence into words.

But there's a catch! The sentence was written by a drunken polyglot and contains words from multiple languages mixed together. Luckily, you've already got a dictionary of which words from different languages cirrespond to each other. So for each word, you should output its `surface form` (as it appears in the input sentence) and `base form` (eg. English). To prevent meaningless interpretations of a sentence as many one-letter words and abbreviations, sort the output by the number of words of each interpretation, lowest first.

Example:

> teeistunnationalgetränkdeeikoku
>
> tee/tea ist/is un/a national/national getränk/drink de/of eikoku/england

Given the dictionary below, the first word  can only be `tee`, German for `tea`. Then comes `is`, which is already the English `is`.  Then `un`, French for `a`. And so on.

> tea => tea, tee, cha
>
> is => is, ist, est, dess
>
> a => a, ein, un, une, aru
>
> national => national, kokkateki
>
> drink => drink, getränk, nomimono
>
> of => of, de, von, no
>
> england => england, angleterre, igirisu, eikoku

Each entry of the dictionary is of the form:

```
<base_form> => <surface_form_1>, <surface_form_2>, ...
```

That is, the dictionary contains the base form (here English is used), and a list of possible variations in different languages for each.

See below for examples with multiple possibilities.

## Scoring

Code-golf.

(Golfed explanation. Ungolfed: The answer with the shortest code as measured by its bytesize in an encoding the interpreter or compiler accepts without additional flags wins. Multiple files add a penalty of 1 byte for each additional file. Flags add to the score.)

## Rules

- The defaults apply, function or program.
- You may assume there exists at least one solution.
- Your program must run in a reasonable amount of time, so don't just try every possible combination of words. Be prepared for a dictionary that contains hundred or thousands of words. Let's say about ~10 minutes on a modern PC.
- You must support unicode, at least the [basic multi-lingual plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), codepoints 0x0000 - 0xFFFF. If your language of choice does not support unicode, you can emulate it using a fixed-length unicode encoding: consider each n bytes of the input sentence a letter.
- You do not need to worry about unicode modifiers, normalizing etc. -- each codepoint is considered a unique "letter".

## Input

- The defaults apply, `stdin`, command line argument, function argument, javascript prompt etc.
- The input sentence is given as a string (`teaist`) or list/array (`[t,e,a,i,s,t]`)
- You may assume the input sentence is already in lower case.
- There is no additional punctuation in the input sentence to take care of.
- However, the input sentence and the dictionary may contain "words" with commas, periods, etc., ie. every unicode codepoint from the basic multilingual plane. It will not contain any of the codepoints 0x00-0x20, which means no null-bytes, spaces, tabs, newlines, so you can use them for separating the output.
- The dictionary may be in any format of your choice, but it must contain an association between a base form and all possible surface forms. It must not list all base forms for each surface form.
- You may also read the dictionary from a file, and take the file name or raw data as input.
- You may also assume the dictionary has already been stored in one variable of your choice. If you do, please provide some code for reference how I can put custom data in it, or read the dictionary from a file. However, it must not be pre-processed and as close to a hash (eg. `{<base_form> => [ <surface_form_1>, <surface_form_2>, ... }`) or array/list (eg. `[ [<base_form>,<surface_form_1>,<surface_form_2>,...], [<base_form>,...], ...]`) as possible in your language.
- You may choose whether the list of surface forms includes the base form or not, eg. `big => big, gross` or `big => gross`.

## Output

- The defaults apply, `stdout`, `stderr`, return value, javascript alert, etc.
- It should not need to be said, but if you output to `stderr`, nothing else but the solution must go to `stderr`, unless it's a compiler/interpreter warning that can be turned off by a flag.
- A list/array of all possible `interpretation`s of splitting the sentence into words, sorted by the number of words.
- Each `interpretation` is a list/array of `word`s. Each word is pair/list/array containing the `surface` form and the `base`, you may choose in which order. The words must be ordered as they appear in the input sentence.
- Alternatively, the array may be flattened.
- Alternatively, output two lists/arrays, one containing the base form for each word, and one the surface form.
- Alternatively, output a string representation of the array/hash/list.

For example, you could output an array

> [["tee","tea"],["est","is"]]

or a flattened array

> ["tee","tea","est","is"]

or two arrays

> ["tee","est"]
>
> ["tea","is"]

or a string representation such as `tee:tea:est:is` or `tee\ttea\nest\tis\n` (`\t` tab, `\n` newline). But make sure you're escaping characters properly.

## Test cases:

First line is the input string. Each following line is a possible way of placing word boundaries, `surface/base`. Afterwards a sample dictionary is provided.

### 1

Note that some words contain a semi-colon.

> abcd;efghi
>
> ab/test  cd;ef/awesome ghi/result
>
> a/only bcd/test ;ef/awesome ghi/result
>
> abcd;efgh/yahoo i/google

with the dictionary:

> test: ab, bcd
>
> awesome: cd;ef, ;ef
>
> result: ghi
>
> only: a
>
> yahoo: abcd;efgh
>
> google: i

### 2

> sumomouserune
>
> sumo/sumo mouse/mouse rune/rune
>
> sumomo/plum useru/lose ne/right

with the dictionary:

> sumo: sumo, mouse:mouse, rune: rune, plum: sumomo, lose: useru, right: ne

### 3

> koukousensei
>
> koukou/school sensei/teacher
>
> koukou/shiptravel sensei/starfortunetelling

with the dictionary

> school: koukou, teacher: sensei, shiptravel: koukou, starfortunetelling: sensei

### 4

unicode support:

> 白雲
>
> 白/sira 雲/kumo
>
> 白/haku 雲/uñ

with the dictionary:

> sira:白, haku:白, kumo:雲, uñ:雲

### 5

Note the order of the results.

> aaaa
>
> aaaa/test
>
> a/test aaa/test
>
> aa/test aa/test
>
> aaa/test a/test
>
> a/test a/test aa/test
>
> a/test aa/test a/test
>
> aa/test a/test a/test
>
> a/test a/test a/test a/test

with the dictionary:

> test: a, aa, aaa, aaaa

I'll add a larger example should I post this.

Comment: This is basically like a previous suggestion I made, but less complicated. My main motivation had been parsing Japanese kanji compounds, hence the unicode support, but I translated it into something more familar to non-Japanese speakers.

Answer (score 1):

### Snake vs labyrinth

Write a program that takes as input a text file representing a labyrinth and checks if this labyrinth can be entirely filled with a snake path. The program should output `true` or `1` if this is the case, `false` or `0` else.

The snake can enter the labyrinth at any point. He can move one cell up, left, right or down; once he has crossed a cell of the grid, he cannot go back to that cell. The snake cannot cross a wall or the borders of the labyrinth.

The labyrinth file is a grid of m x n characters, containing either # (wall) or . (empty space).

**Example 1**

should return *true*

```
.
```

**Example 2**

should return *true*

```
..
..
```

Possible solution (S = snake start, E = snake end, v = go down, < = go left)

```
Sv
E<
```

**Example 3**

should return *true*

```
...
.#.
...
```

Possible solution (S = snake start, E = snake end, v = go down, < = go left, > = go right, ^ = go up)

```
S>v
E#v
^<<
```

**Example 4**

should return *false*

```
.#
#.
```

**Example 5**

should return *false*

```
#.#
...
```

**Example 6**

should return *false*

```
.#.
...
...
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

Comment: I take it there aren't any limitations on efficiency? I seem to remember it's an open problem whether HAM-PATH is hard on subgraphs of the grid graph, and if so, you won't be getting an poly-time algorithms.

Comment: @xnor Yes, no limitations on time/efficiency

Answer (score 1):

Given an input, calculate the correct suffix and output the number in a readable format. The suffixes must go to at least 10^3000, in which the rules for calculating them can be found [here](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/math/number/howhigh.html), or a list can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8rfxYtZZ).

For example:

```
10000 = 10.0 thousand
135933445 = 135.93 million
-2 = -2.0
-2.36734603 = -2.37
'1'+'9'*3000 = 2.0 nongennovemnonagintillion
```

**Rules:**

- No getting things from external resources - it must all be calculated within the code.
- External modules are fine as long as it doesn't breach the above rule.
- The input should work when input as a string, integer or float.
- The output must always contain a decimal place.
- The output must be rounded if above 2 decimal places.
- Leaving zeroes at the end is optional, as long as it doesn't go above 2 decimals (1.00 or 1.0 are both fine) and is consistent for all inputs (1 should output the same as 1.0).
- Must not throw an error no matter how high or low the input is.

**Scoring:**

- Score is the length of the code, including indents.
- Lowest score wins.
- It does not need to be a function, printing the output is fine.

As a starting point, here is an ungolfed version of some code to generate the list of suffixes. Feel free to build upon this or start from scratch.

```
a = ['', 'un','duo','tre','quattor','quin','sex','septen','octo','novem']
c = ['tillion', 'decillion', 'vigintillion', 'trigintillion', 'quadragintillion', 'quinquagintillion', 'sexagintillion', 'septuagintillion', 'octogintillion', 'nonagintillion']
d = ['', 'cen', 'duocen', 'trecen', 'quadringen', 'quingen', 'sescen', 'septingen', 'octingen', 'nongen']

num_dict = ['']
num_dict.append('thousand')
num_dict.append('million')
num_dict.append('billion')
num_dict.append('trillion')
num_dict.append('quadrillion')
num_dict.append('quintillion')
num_dict.append('sextillion')
num_dict.append('septillion')
num_dict.append('octillion')
num_dict.append('nonillion')

for prefix_hundreds in d:

    #tillion can't be used first time round
    if not prefix_hundreds:
        b = c[1:]
    else:
        b = c

    for prefix_tens in b:
        for prefix in a:
            num_dict.append(prefix_hundreds+prefix+prefix_tens)
```

For the record, my result is 578 characters. To be fair I'm surprised I couldn't find this being asked before :P

Comment: The meat of this challenge is basically just the reverse of [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40523/14215), which may explain why you haven't seen it this way.

Comment: "*The input can be in any format, not just integers.*" is far too vague. "*The output must be rounded if too long.*" needs to define "too long", and ideally give a rounding rule (e.g. floor, ceiling, nearest half-up, nearest half-down, nearest half-even, nearest half-odd).

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'd missed the first answer, that is quite similar haha. This one should use 10x the values and may golf better with outputting the number instead of reading the input. And is the rounding rule actually needed? I generally meant what the default rounding functions do (that you learn in school), which is like half up, but then half down when you're below 0.

Comment: Ended up busy with other stuff recently so only just remembered about this, would it be worth posting, or is it too similar to that other question?

Answer (score 1):

A [covering array](http://math.nist.gov/coveringarrays/coveringarray.html) is an `N` by `k` array in which each element is one of {0, 1, ..., v-1} (so `v` symbols in total), and for any `t` columns chosen (so an `N` x `t` array) contains all possible `v^t` tuples.

**Input:** `N`, `k`, `t`, `v` (all 4 are positive integers), and then `N` x `k` integers, each of which comes from {0, ..., v-1}. Each of the integers are separated by spaces.

**Output:** `Yes` if the input is a valid covering array, and `No` if it is not.

**Goal:** in any language you want, write a program that validates if the input is a covering array in the *fastest* time. I will run programs on my machine, which is a Macbook Pro 2.2 Ghz Intel i7 with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Are you planning a follow-up which asks people to generate minimal covering arrays? That seems to be the more interesting direction.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's actually a cool idea, but other than `v=t=2`, the minimal case is not known, and no explicit construction is known (other than orthogonal arrays, which only work for one value of `k`). One question could be to ask for the *best known minimal* CA, which is actually something I'd really like (because it is part of my research).

Comment: I was thinking of a [tag:code-challenge] which scores by the best CA for certain parameters, possibly required to be deterministic and inside a certain time limit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I like that idea, possibly allowing any technique such as simulated annealing.

Answer (score 1):

## KOTH Simpleton's Chess

### Introduction

#### Disclaimer: The word "simpleton" is not meant to offend anyone who is simple or anything else. Don't take it personally, please.

It is a lovely afternoon at the Completely Average Chess Club, and like most afternoons, the chess players, who are also part-time code golfers, are golfing programs to play chess. They use incredibly complicated move-finding algorithms and are golfing them down into 4 byte programs. However, on this particular afternoon, some aliens, who are looking to use human intelligence to play alien chess, steal the chess players' intelligence, turning them into simpletons! Now they can't even remember all the pieces, let alone perform an alpha-beta tree-search.

Today, we won't be focusing on restoring the chess players' minds back. Instead, we'll be playing a modified chess game with simpler rules!

### Rules

#### The pieces

Like regular chess, Simpleton Chess has two teams: white and black. Unlike regular chess, however, Simpleton Chess only has one piece that can attack north, north west and north east and can move two squares at a time. If you are familiar with regular chess, this is much like the pawn except for the fact you can attack forward (or north) and can move two squares at a time. Like regular chess, to take a piece you must move in the place of the piece that you wish to take. If there is a piece in of you, and you move 1 square in front, then you will take that piece.

Castling and en passant are ignored.

#### Winning the game

To win the game, you must take all the pieces of the opposing team.

#### Time limit

Each entry has an allowed time is 3 minutes (180000ms).

#### The board

Any piece that moves outside the board will disqualify you. The board is a 2D int array that you can access by assigning a variable to `SimpletonUtils.read`

#### Entries

Your entry is expected to have two methods: `getName()` and `move()`.

The `getName()` method will return a `String` of the name of your entry.

The move method is a `void` and is called every time you need to move.

To submit the board you use `SimpletonUtils.submitBoard`

Entries are suggested (and very, very much encouraged) to verify the board using `SimpletonUtils.verifyBoard` (you have 3 minutes, no need to worry about speed). You will be disqualified if you submit an invalid board, however, you will not be disqualified for sending an invalid board to `SimpletonUtils.verifyBoard`. If you don't verify the board, a warning will be sent to console output if debug is on (edit SimpletonConfig.java).

Entry template

Here is an example entry to follow:

```
package SimpletonChess;
import SimpletonChess.SimpletonPlayer;
import SimpletonChess.SimpletonUtils;

public class MyEntry extends SimpletonPlayer {

    /**
     * Return the name of our bot to the controller
     */
    public String getName(){
        return "MyEntry";
    }

    /**
     * Method to carry out the logic for our entry
     */
    public void move(){
        SimpletonUtils utils = new SimpletonUtils();
        int[][] board = utils.read(); // Your own local copy of the board

        /*
        * TODO: Template. Add logic here
        */

       utils.submitBoard(board); // Note that you will be disqualified if your board is invalid! Check it with utils.verifyBoard(board), just use an if statement.
    }

}
```

** Remember to add your entry to the controller's main class, SimpletonTournament.java, when you're finished! **

#### Controller

The controller is on GitHub. (Link will be added when the controller is ready)

Your entries are expected to be written in Java *(unless I find the time to write a console parser)*.

### Final words

Good luck simpletons! I would very much like to see an entry using the *monte carlo method*, that would be splendid!

Also, a fantastic link for all things chess programming related: http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/

That's it from me, send your entries over today!

---

**Notes**

- I know there is another KOTH chess tournament. I don't think this is a duplicate since it has simpler rules and different pieces
- Is this too similar to checkers?

---

**TODOs**

- <s>Fix overbolding</s>
- <s>Fix possibility to mess up the board with illegal moves</s> (feedback needed)
- <s>Themed intro, since a lot of other people are doing it</s> (feedback needed!)
- **Finish controller**
- Add some diagrams
- Fix numerous typos and formatting errors

Comment: "_Any pieces that the board will be deleted_"  Did you mean "_Any pieces that the board contains will be deleted_"? Also, your KOTH seems to have too much **boldness** . Use `bacticks`(\`) instead of **bold** for code formatting and try to use **bold** whenever appropriate..

Comment: From your description of the move method, it sounds like an entry has the opportunity to change data that it shouldn't be allowed to change. We all tend to be sportsmanlike here, and I'm sure nobody would try to game the system like that, but you should try not to make such things available. And anyway, if somebody tries to obfuscate their code, or has a bug, an accident could end up catastrophic. I don't know how rigorous your movechecking will be, but be careful.

Comment: What size is the board? Does a piece which gets level with the rearmost of the opponent's pieces become irrelevant except as a guarantee that you can't lose?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback everyone. CoolGuy: My apologies for over-bolding, will fix. I was editing in another editor, not on StackExchange. @BrainSteel I will play around with various ways of making sure moves are not illegal. Any ideas for how I can make it impossible to unfairly change the board? I'm not very sure about this one, and I'll have a look at other KOTHs to see how they handle it. If you have any suggestions please let me know. Peter Taylor: The size of the board is 8x8.

Comment: @BrainSteel I have now finished a system for checking the move which should stop people from changing the board. They receive a local copy of the board and must submit it back with `submitBoard` (hence now `move()` is a void). So now I can do move checking. There will also be a method called `verify` which will verify the board.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a fine way to handle it! You can never be too careful. I await your controller!

Comment: Some diagrams/images would really help clarify the rules- for example the starting set up - I assume each player starts with two rows of pieces at their end of the board but this is not clear. Also a diagram showing the allowable moves would be really great. What happens when one of your pieces reaches the opposite edge of the board and cannot be taken. Other than that looks like a really interesting challenge and looking forward to it... :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! @TheE Controller is on its way. Might take a while... I code as slow as a tortoise ;)

Comment: I don't think the themed intro adds anything.

Answer (score 1):

## How Many Isomers of Nonane / Undecane Are There?

**Background**

Hydrogen and carbon form various series of compounds called hydrocarbons. Carbon forms four bonds and hydrogen forms 1 bond. The alkanes are the series of hydrocarbons without any double bonds between carbon atoms.  The first four alkanes are shown below. Hydrogen atoms are omitted for simplicity. We know each carbon forms four bonds, so the unused bonds must have hydrogen atoms on them.

```
Methane     Ethane    Propane    n-Butane    Isobutane
C           C-C       C-C-C          C-C     C-C-C
                                       |       |
                                     C-C       C
```

Note that Methane, Ethane and Propane have only one isomer, whereas Butane comes in two isomeric forms. Both have four carbon atoms but in n-Butane they are arranged in a continuous chain, whereas in Isobutane (also known as 2-Methyl Propane) they are arranged as a continuous chain of 3 atoms plus a side branch of one carbon atom.

In both cases, the ten loose bonds on the carbon atoms are occupied by hydrogen atoms. In general, for hydrocarbons with no rings or multiple bonds, the formula is `Cn H(2+2n)`.

**Task**

1. Your task is to create a program or function that accepts a single integer `0 < n < 10` and outputs to STDOUT or a file all the possible structural isomers of the hydrocarbon of formula `Cn H(2+2n)`. That is to say, all the different ways in which n carbon atoms can be connected together, assuming freedom to twist about all bonds.
2. The carbon atoms shall be represented by the symbol `C`. In the interest of simplicity, hydrogen atoms shall be omitted.
   The bonds shall be represented by the symbols `-` and `|`. Only horizontal and vertical bonds are allowed.
   Each isomer shall be represented by a network of carbon atoms separated by bonds. As such the character `C` will appear on a grid of pitch 2x2.
3. Your program / function shall draw each possible isomer once and only once. The type of isomerism to be considered is structural isomerism. That is to say, compounds with different branching patterns shall be considered different. Different stereoisomers and different conformations shall be considered equivalent. Any conformation that complies with Rule 2 is valid.
4. The different isomers shall be displayed one below the other, in any order. To assist in checking, each isomer shall be preceded by a sequential number (starting at 1) on its own line. There shall be no more than 5 blank lines between any isomer and the preceding / following numbers. Unnecesary whitespace to the left and right of each isomer shall not exceed 10 characters in either direction.
5. To avoid extreme brute force solutions, execution time shall not exceed 1 minute on my machine for any input case.
6. **Scoring: This code golf. Shortest code wins. If your program can handle up to `n=11` instead of `n=9` there is a -50% bonus.** Above `n=9` is significantly harder, because the sidechains can themselves have sidechains.

Above n=11 there exist some isomers that cannot be represented according to the rules of this question as some atoms would overlap.

The number of isomers for each value of n is given in https://oeis.org/A000602. Note that behaviour for n=0 can be undefined. The names of the isomers are here: http://www.kentchemistry.com/links/organic/isomersofalkanes.htm

```
n       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9  10   11   
isomers 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 18, 35, 75, 159
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT n=6 (all 5 possible isomers)**
Note: you must display the isomers one below the other. They are displayed side by side here to save space. For further explanation, a video explaining structural isomerism with this example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOhEJK4Umds

```
1            2          3           4         5
                                                C
                                                |
C-C-C-C-C-C  C-C-C-C-C  C-C-C-C-C   C-C-C-C   C-C-C-C
               |            |         | |       |
               C            C         C C       C
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT n=8 (only some of the possible isomers, you must display them all.)**

**n-Octane**

```
C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C
```

**3,4dimethyloctane.** Those who know about stereoisomerism will know that in 3 dimensions the bonds are arranged in a tetrahedron around the carbon atom. This means that this compound can exist in 3 distinct forms: a lefthand form, a righthand form and a mirror symmetric form. For the purpose of this question these are equivalent and any **one** of the following is acceptable (and there are many other acceptable ways of drawing this isomer.)

```
    C-C-C-C          C          C-C-C-C             C          C-C-C-C       C-C-C-C-C-C  
      |              |              |               |            |               | |
  C-C-C-C      C-C-C-C-C-C        C-C-C-C       C-C-C-C-C-C    C-C-C-C           C C
                   |                                  |    
                   C                                  C
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT n=10 (only some of the possible isomers, you must display them all.)**

**triisopropylmethane, or 2(methylethyl)1,3dimethylpentane** (n=10 is the smallest n where there can be a sidechain of three C atoms, and therefore also the smallest n where a sidechain itself can be branched.)

```
    C   C
    |   |
  C-C-C-C-C
      |
    C-C-C
```

**2,2,3,4,4pentamethylpentane** (it can be shown that for n=10 a maximum of 2 carbon atoms can be completely surrounded by four other carbon atoms each.)

```
  C   C
  |   |
C-C-C-C-C
  | | |
  C C C
```

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before, but I can't find it. Is code challenge (with codegolf tie break) the best scoring? I'm not sure about making it a codegolf, because I think the higher `n` are probably quite hard and it would discourage participation.

Comment: Do enantiomers count twice?

Comment: "*Your task is to create a program or function that accepts a single integer `0 < n < 12` ... The winning entry will be the program that produces correct output for the highest value of n ... Above n=11 there exist some isomers ... that cannot be represented according to the rules of this question*" What I understand from this is that every valid submission gets the same score, which seems a bit pointless. With the given tie-breaker, it's effectively just a [tag:code-golf].

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've changed it to a codegolf for n=9, plus a generous bonus for n=11. n>9 is fiddly (more for display reasons than underlying maths) because sometimes the sidechains have sidechains.  I want to see all the way to n=11, but I don't want to exclude people by making it too hard.

Comment: @feersum to avoid complication, enantiomers and other types of stereoisomers are considered equivalent, you should only include one of them for each structural isomer. In any case they can't be distinguished properly  according to the display spec. Bond symbols such as `<` and `>` would be needed to show whether an atom is closer/further than another. I thought this was clear from rule 3 and example 3,4 dimethyloctane, but I'm not surprised someone asked. Is there a way to make this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

## Solve the nonogram

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Nonograms, also known as Hankie or Picross, are fascinating. They are really simple is essence, but to solve the most complexe one, some tricks have to be learned.

### Basics

Nonograms are usually presented this way :

```
           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|
  2 2|
1 1 1|
  2 2|
    3|
```

The numbers in lines and columns determine how much box in a row will be present, and how much sets there will be on this line/columns.
The seconde line says `2 2`which means "2 boxes in a row, at least one space, 2 boxes in a row"
Let's give it a try with the 5x5 sample above.
I will use `#`for boxes and `.`for blank confirmed.

```
           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|
  2 2|
1 1 1|
  2 2|
    3|
As we said, second line says 2,some spaces,2. 
As we are playing on a 5x5 board, there's only one space remaining after 
putting the boxes, so their position is certain.
           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|
  2 2| # # . # #
1 1 1|
  2 2|
    3|
There's some other 2 2 rows, let's fill them !

           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|   #   #
  2 2| # # . # #
1 1 1|   .   .
  2 2| # # . # #
    3|   #   #

We can say this puzzle is over :
Look at the 1 1 1 rows, they have already 2 blank confirmed
which means there's only 3 spaces left. We can fill these, and complete the
puzzle.

           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|   # # #
  2 2| # # . # #
1 1 1| # . # . #
  2 2| # # . # #
    3|   # # #

We didn't checked all confirmed blank, but it's not the matter, we only need
to check the boxes. Note that the 3 rows has been useless to solve this 
puzzle.
```

There you got the basics, but some tips on [the wikipedia page could be useful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Nonogram)

### Goal

Your job is to write a program in the language you want to solve nonograms.

There shouldn't be any problem, but here's some [loopholes that are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41019), just in case :).

I'd also like you to write which down command have to be run to execute your code, and

### Input

The input can be graphic, an array, a string via stdin, or whatever you want. You may hard-code it, I want to know how fast your program is to solve nonograms, not how fast it is to parse datas.
I'll provide two format for each test case. A ASCII-Art'd one, as shown above, and one structured as an array in the form :

```
 [[columns],[lines]]
 columns and line will also be noted the same way, the array for the sample :
 [[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2],[3]],[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2],[3]]]
```

### Output

You must produce the solved nonogram, formated as you want as long as it is clear. It should be outputed via stdout, or your language closest alternative, as an Image, Ascii-art or left on top of the stack.

### Test Cases

Puzzles will never be greater than 99*99, nor smaller than 2*2.They all are solvable by using basic techniques, the ones shown on wikipedia are far more than enough.

I might add some test cases latter, but big ones take time, a lot of time. If you want to give it a try, post one with your answer, and it will be added if it is solvable without any guess. Which means solving only those one won't be necessary nice, you need to be able to solve any "basic" nonogram : No multi-row - multi depth contradiction looking. Even contradiction shouldn't be necessary

```
5x5
[[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2],[3]],[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2],[3]]]

           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +-----------
    3|
  2 2|
1 1 1|
  2 2|
    3|

10x10

[[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2],[3],[3,1],[2,7],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3]],[[3],[2,2],[1,1,1],[3,2,2],[2,2,3],[1,1,1,1],[2,4,1],[3,1,2],[4],[1]]]

                       1
             1         1 2
           2 1 2   3 2 1 2 3
         3 2 1 2 3 1 7 1 2 3
       +--------------------
      3|
    2 2|
  1 1 1|
  3 2 2|
  2 2 3|
1 1 1 1|
  2 4 1|
  3 1 2|
      4|
      1| 

30x30

[[[10,6,10],[9,8,9],[7,10,7],[7,14,6],[6,15,5],[6,15,5],[5,17,4],[5,19,4],[26,3],[4,2,10,2,3],[4,1,8,1,3],[3,12,3],[3,9,3],[3,16,3],[3,16,3][3,16,3][3,16,3][3,16,3],[3,9,3],[3,12,3],[3,1,8,1,3],[4,2,10,2,3],[4,25],[4,19,4],[5,17,5],[6,16,5],[6,12,7],[8,10,8],[8,8,10],[10,6,10]]

                                  4 4                   3 4
                                  2 1                   1 2
               10 9 7 7 6 6 5 5  10 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 810   4 5 6 6 8 810
                6 810141515171926 2 112 91616161616 912 1 2 41917161210 8 6
               10 9 7 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 325 4 5 5 7 81011 
              +------------------------------------------------------------
            30|
            30|
            30|
          11 9|
           9 6|
   6 3 1 1 3 5|
   4 3 1 1 3 3|
   2 3 2 2 4 3|
     2 6 5 4 1|
     1 6 5 5 1|
         7 5 6|
         9 7 8|
            30|
            30|
            30|
            30|
            30|
            30|
            28|
          26 1|
 1 7 1 5 1 6 2|
 2 6 1 3 1 4 2|
 2 5 1 3 1 4 3|
 3 3 1 1 1 3 4|
     4 3 1 3 4|
       6 3 3 6|
           8 8|
            30|
            30|
            30|
```

### Solution

For those who are interested, here's the solution for the test cases.

```
 5x5

           1
         2 1 2
       3 2 1 2 3
     +----------
    3| . # # # .
  2 2| # # . # #
1 1 1| # . # . #
  2 2| # # . # #
    3| . # # # .

10x10
                       1
             1         1 2
           2 1 2   3 2 1 2 3
         3 2 1 2 3 1 7 1 2 3
       +--------------------
      3| . . . . . . # # # .
    2 2| . . . . . # # . # #
  1 1 1| . . . . . # . # . #
  3 2 2| . # # # . # # . # #
  2 2 3| # # . # # . # # # .
1 1 1 1| # . # . # . # . . .
  2 4 1| # # . # # # # . . #
  3 1 2| . # # # . # # . # #
      4| . . . . . . # # # #
      1| . . . . . . # . . .

30x30
Hope you'll like it, it took me a lot of time :)
                                  4 4                   3 4
                                  2 1                   1 2
               10 9 7 7 6 6 5 5  10 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 810   4 5 6 6 8 810
                6 810141515171926 2 112 91616161616 912 1 2 41917161210 8 6
               10 9 7 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 325 4 5 5 7 81011 
              +------------------------------------------------------------
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
          11 9| # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # #
           9 6| # # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # #
   6 3 1 1 3 5| # # # # # # . . # # # . . # . . . # . . # # # . . # # # # #
   4 3 1 1 3 3| # # # # . . . # # # . . . # . . . # . . . # # # . . . # # #
   2 3 2 2 4 3| # # . . . . # # # . . . . # # . # # . . . . # # # # . # # #
     2 6 5 4 1| # # . # # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . . . # # # # . . . #
     1 6 5 5 1| # . . # # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . #
         7 5 6| . . # # # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . . . # # # # # # . .
         9 7 8| . # # # # # # # # # . . # # # # # # # . . # # # # # # # # .
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            28| . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # .
          26 1| . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . #
 1 7 1 5 1 6 2| # . . # # # # # # # . # . # # # # # . # . # # # # # # . # #
 2 6 1 3 1 4 2| # # . # # # # # # . . # . . # # # . . # . . # # # # . . # #
 2 5 1 3 1 4 3| # # . . # # # # # . . # . . # # # . . # . . # # # # . # # #
 3 3 1 1 1 3 4| # # # . . . # # # . . # . . . # . . . # . . # # # . # # # #
     4 3 1 3 4| # # # # . . . # # # . . . . . # . . . . . # # # . . # # # #
       6 3 3 6| # # # # # # . . # # # . . . . . . . . . # # # . # # # # # #
           8 8| # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
            30| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
60x60
Not completed, not tested

                              60| # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
                     6 3 1 1 335| # # # # # # . . # # # . . # . . . # . . # # # . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
             6 3 1 1 3 6 6 5 5 1| # # # # # # . . # # # . . # . . . # . . # # # . . # # # # # # . . # # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . . . # # # # # . . #
                             647| . # # # # # # . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
                   5 1 1 3 2 1 4| # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # # # . # # . # . . . . # # # #
                   1 2 1 2 2 1 4| . # . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . # . . . . # # # #
                     1 2 1 2 1 3| # . . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # # . # . . . . . # # #
                       2 2 1 1 2| # # . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . # . . . . . . . . # #
                           3 2 2| # # # . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # #
                           3 2 1| # # # . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                           3 3 1| . # # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                             1 8| # . # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                         1 4 4 1| # . # # # # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                         1 3 2 2| # . # # # . . . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # #
                         1 3 2 1| # . . # # # . . . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                         2 4 3 1| # # . # # # # . . . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # .
                         4 3 3 2| # # # # . # # # . . . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # #
                         3 4 3 1| . # # # . . # # # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                           1 3 8| # . # # # . # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                       1 3 1 5 1| # . # # # . # . # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
                         1 5 4 2| # . # # # # # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # #
                       2 4 2 3 2| # # . # # # # . # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # .
                   2 2 2 1 3 2 1| # # . # # . # # . # . . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . #
                   1 2 2 1 3 2 2| . # . # # . # # . # . . . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # #
                   3 1 2 2 4 2 2| # # # . # . # # . # # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # .
                 3 1 2 4 3 2 2 1| # # # . # . # # . # # # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . #
               1 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2| # . # # . # # . # # # . # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . # #
               1 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2| # . # # . # # . # # # . # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . # # .
                 4 2 6 4 2 2 2 1| # # # # . # # . # # # # # # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . # # . #
                   6 6 4 2 2 2 2| . # # # # # # . # # # # # # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . # # . # # . # #
               3 3 2 3 5 3 2 2 2| # # # . # # # . # # . # # # . # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # . # # . # # . # #
             1 1 3 2 6 3 4 2 2 2| # . # . # # # . # # . # # # # # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # . # # . # # . # #
         1 5 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 1| # . # # # # # . # # . # # . # . # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . # # . # # . # # . #
         1 3 1 2 2 1 1 4 3 2 2 2| # . # # # . # . # # . # # . # . # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # . . . # # . # # . # # .
           1 3 1 2 2 3 4 4 2 2 2| # . # # # . # . # # . # # . # # # . . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # . . . . # # . # # . # #
       1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 2 2 2 2 1| # . # . # . # . # # . # # . # # # . . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . # # . . . . # # . # # . #
             3 6 2 4 1 3 3 2 2 2| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # . . . # # . . . . # # . # # .
           2 2 3 2 4 1 4 4 2 2 2| . # # . # # . # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . # #
       2 2 3 2 1 1 1 4 2 2 2 2 1| # # . . # # . # # # . # # . # . . # . # . # # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
         2 6 2 1 2 1 2 3 3 2 2 2| # # . . # # # # # # . # # . # . # # . # . # # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # .
           4 5 4 2 1 1 3 4 2 2 2| # # # # . # # # # # . # # # # . # # . # . # . . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # #
         3 5 4 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1| . # # # . # # # # # . # # # # . # # . # . # . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . #
           8 4 4 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1| # # # # # # # # . # # # # . # # # # . # . # # . # . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . . # .
         3 4 1 2 4 1 3 2 2 2 2 2| # # # . # # # # . # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . # #
           3 6 2 4 1 6 4 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # # # . . . . . # # # # . . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
       3 6 2 4 1 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . # # . . . # # . # # . . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
       3 6 2 4 1 5 1 1 3 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # # . # . . . # . # # # . . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
           3 6 2 4 1 212 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # . # # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
       3 6 2 4 1 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # . # . . . . # . . . . # # # . . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
           3 6 2 4 1 4 1 4 2 2 4| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # # # . . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # # #
         3 6 2 4 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 4| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # . # # . . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # # #
         3 6 2 4 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 3| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # # .
         3 6 2 4 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 4| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # # #
       3 6 2 4 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
       3 6 2 4 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . . # . . . . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
       3 6 2 4 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . . # # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
   3 6 2 4 1 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . . # . # . # . . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . . . # # . . . . # # . #
 3 6 2 4 1 4 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . # # . # . # # . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . # . # # . . . . # # . #
   3 6 2 4 1 4 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 4| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . # # . # . # # . # # . . . # # . . . # # . . # . # # . . . # # # # .
         3 6 2 4 1 4 2 1 6 4 412| # # # . # # # # # # . # # . # # # # . # . # # # # . # # . # . # # # # # # . # # # # . # # # # . # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

### Winning criteria

Puzzle solving might be long, who will find the best heuristics? Who will find the best implementation? Fastest code will win (code will be running on my computer, i5-4440, and must not use more than 4GB of RAM). 
You'll be scored using the 60*60 nonogram `sandbox note : have to be added`. Other test cases are here to help you while developing your submission.
If there's a need of a Tie-breaker, i'll provide more complex test case (maybe a 90*90?)

### Sandbox

I have two questions for the sandbox :

- Do I need to put more explanations?
- Is there too much grammar/others faults? (I'm not native, sorry :()

As suggested by @steveverrill, I changed it to a fastest-code contest, some basic things changed. It makes much more sense, thanks.

I added the first part of the 60x60 nonogram, still have to form the array, and do the columns. I know it is ugly, but I wasn't able to come with a nice one which would be viable AND long to solve. T

Comment: You really need some time limit on this, and for a specified size. "don't try to brute force it" is vague. The shortest-code way of solving this will be to try every possible combination of 0's and 1's and check. That will take less than a second for example 1, a lifetime for example 2, and something like the current age of the universe for example 3. There are other marginally less naive ways of doing it, like generating all possible rows then checking the colums, which will also take too long. I'd go as far as to say this might go better as fastest code (largest example solved in 1 minute.)

Comment: Did you make that batman yourself? Are you sure it's the only valid solution? (doesn't matter so long as you specify that the program can terminate when it finds *any* valid solution.) Note that a human will immediately note the completely full rows and the (near) symmetry, which it will make it easier, while a computer will not.

Comment: @steveverrill I was thinking of 2~3 minutes for the 30*30 one, I don't want it to take some billion years :). But I'll take your fastest code in consideration, as it may have more sense, and could be interesting to see what people will bring.

Comment: @steveverrill Yes I did, and there shouldn't be any other solution. But as per the rules of a nonogram, any solution satisfying lines/columns is a good one, just less prettier than the intended one. Using symettry is useless to solve this one. I solved it only using the "30 is length of the row, I fill", "27 2 means w+27+x+2+y=30, 30- 27+2=29 so w=y=0 and x=1" plus an other strategie designed as "simple boxes" on the wikipedia page. This is the basic movement a beginner learn, and they shouldn't be hard to code them as they can be done line-by-line and column-by-column

Comment: Are you sure your 30x30 has only one solution?

Comment: @Sparr I'm still testing to find other ones, but I can't find an other one

Comment: I see you're aware fastest code means you must take reponsibilty for running the code. Score should either be: 1. time to solve a given grid size, or 2. max (square?) grid size solved in a given time. simply "fastest code" is not enough. The trouble with 1 is you've no idea how long it will take (see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5360/15599). The trouble with 2 is you may have to define additional grids, but I think that's preferable over 1. Users can time themselves on the test cases to give an idea of the winner - probably there will be vast differences in timing..

Comment: @steveverrill I'm going for 2., surely with a 60*60 or 70*70 grid (would be hard to design a greater one). I think it has enough cells to see who's the best. If not, i'll push myself into a 90*90 one.

Comment: According to Wikipedia this problema is NP-hard. That means grid size will have a massive impact on time. It's not at all clear whether 30x30 will run in reasonable time. If you want to score by time to complete a certain grid, I suggest you start with the smallest grid, eliminate all entries that run a measurable time (say 1 second) slower than the leader, then proceed to do the same with larger and larger grids until only one entry remains. That way you can avoid the problem of timings that are ridiculously fast or ridiculously slow. It also means the entries get tested on a variety of grids

Comment: Oops- just seen the new note about "solveable without any guess"! If anyone encodes an algorithm for that (I'm guessing a máximum of 2 people will do that, it's easy for a human to do but quite difficult to code) it should run very fast. If it is *guaranteed* that no guessing is required this becomes quite a different challenge. Is it guaranteed?

Comment: @steveverrill I might try to code a submission, to see how much time it would take. It could be used by others as a scale to see how far they are from it. A real nonogram must be solved by logic only. It can be complicated logic (while you predict what 2+ boxes placed would do on the board(depth-reasoning)). I don't think I'll be able to prove that point, but I tried for those 3 every way I could to solve them, and each time no guesses were needed. That's the reason it is long to design one ^^'.

Comment: The challenge is currently self-contradictory, asking "Who will find the best heuristics?" but promising "they are all solvable using basic techniques." If it is going to be a fastest-code and not a code golf, then the puzzles should be as difficult as possible.

Comment: @feersum The fact they are all solvable by basics is because it was initially a code-golf. The 60*60 I'm designing will be a bit more trickier to solve, and I might prepare a 40*40 as an intermediate tricky case. But yeah, thanks for denoting this fact, I might have forgotten.

Comment: i know this game and i cant solve it another way aside bruteforce, sorry but i thnk this challenge wouldnt give desired results

Answer (score 1):

## 4-Way Intersection Simulator

Consider an intersection as follows:

[image]

Cars will drive up any of the above `Input` lanes, and will exit out of any of the 3 other `Output` lanes.  **The goal is to take the list of cars, their arrival time, and their destination, and to return the times they will exit the intersection**.

We will measure the time that it takes a car to cross an intersection as 1 **Tick**.  We will assume that the time it takes for a car to approach and leave the intersection to be 0 ticks.

Each input acts as a queue of cars.  Each tick, **the car that has been at the front of its respective lane the longest will cross the intersection** in his respective direction.

## Priority

If multiple cars have been waiting for the same amount of time, the rightmost car has priority.  If there are 2 cars that are on opposing sides, they will both cross at the same time (as described below), unless only one of them is turning left.  If that is the case, the car not turning left will have priority.  Two cars may turn left at the same time.  If there are 4 cars that arrive at the same time, the car in Input 1 will have priority.

After the car to cross has been chosen, other cars may cross at the same time, assuming their paths don't cross.  Priority is given to the lane directly across from the crossing car, then to the car to right, then to the car to his left.

## Input/Output

Input will be a list of cars.  Each car will be passed as a tuple containing the cars' unique ID, arrival time, arrival lane, and destination lane.  The arrival lane will never be the destination lane.

Your program should output a list of cars, where each car is a tuple containing the cars' unique ID and the time it reaches its destination.

I don't care if the input format exactly matches the examples below.  What I do care is that you input a list of tuples/lists and output a list of tuples/lists.

## Examples

```
[(0, 5, 2, 3)] -> [(0, 6)] 
Car 0 arrives in lane 2 at tick 5.  He leaves in lane 3 at tick 6

[(0, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 3, 1)] -> [(0, 4), (1, 4)] 
Car 0 and 1 arrive in lanes 1 and 3 at tick 3.  They both leave at tick 4.

[(0, 0, 3, 1), (1, 0, 4, 2), (2, 1, 4, 2)] -> [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3)]
Car 0 and 1 arrive in lanes 3 and 4.  Their paths intersect, so car 1 leaves first 
because it is the rightmost car.  The next tick, car 2 arrives, but car 0 has been 
waiting the longest, so car 0 leaves next.  Finally, car 2 leaves at time 3.

[(0, 0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2, 3), (2, 0, 3, 4), (3, 0, 4, 2)] -> [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
All four cars arrive at the same time.  Car 0 has the priority as it is in Input 1.  
Car 2 is directly across from it, and both are turning left, so they cross at the same 
time.  Car 1 is turning left, so car 3 will cross next, followed by Car 1.

[(0, 0, 1, 4), (1, 0, 2, 1), (2, 0, 3, 2), (3, 0, 4, 3)] -> [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
All four cars arrive at the same time, all are turning right, so all leave at tick 1.

[(0, 0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 4, 2), (2, 0, 3, 2), (3, 1, 1, 4), (4, 1, 4, 1), (5, 1, 2, 1), (6, 2, 3, 4), (7, 2, 1, 3), (8, 3, 1, 4), (9, 3, 4, 2), (10, 3, 3, 2)] -> [(0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (6, 3), (4, 4), (10, 4), (7, 5), (9, 6), (8, 6)]
Car 2 is the rightmost, and has priority.  Car 0 is also able to cross at Tick 0
Car 1 has now been waiting the longest, and has priority.  Both Car 3 and 5 are able to
cross as well.  Car 4 was waiting behind Car 1, and so Cars 4, 6, and 7 arrive at the
same time.  Car 6 is the rightmost, so he exits at tick 3 while cars 8-10 arrive.
Car 4 is the next rightmost, so he makes his turn next, while Car 10 makes his right turn.
Car 7 finally has his turn, and crosses.  Car 8 is behind Car 7, and Car 9 intersects with
Car 7, so neither cross at the same time, but both are able to cross the next tick.
```

Comment: @Dennis updated, thank you.

Comment: [Related sandboxed KOTH](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5239/31054)

Answer (score 1):

## Black and White Morphing

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Given two black and white images, the goal is creating a animated black and white gif that transforms one image into the other and back.

The catch is, that for all frames the number of black pixels (as well as the number of white pixels, obviously) stays the same. You can assume that the two input images have the exact same size and the exact same number of black pixels.

#### *Discussion*

*@PeterTaylor suggested making the restrictions that from one frame to the next you can only swap adjecent pixels. Otherwise this challenge would be almost the same as [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/american-gothic-in-the-palette-of-mona-lisa-rearrange-the-pixels), so we need a further restriction.*

*My goal is enforcing a 'slow' transition that can produce nice effects. One way of picturing that was considering the white pixels as fluid or sand that has to be rearranged step by step into the other image.*

*@trichoplax suggested making the limit that e.g. only 5% of the pixels may change in each transition.*

#### Test Cases

This is a first series of test cases, all 320x386px and 33844 white pixels.

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Is the stark contrast how you want to the challenge to look, or just what you happen to have at the moment? How would you feel about including dithered images that use the same number of white pixels as these but give the impression of grayscale, and make more detail visible in the currently pure black and pure white regions?

Comment: Would it provide more challenge and more variety to include more than one value for number of white pixels? Perhaps the same 5 images could be provided in 3 categories: black heavy, white heavy and balanced. Then the results for each category can be shown so we can judge whether a given technique gives good results across the board.

Comment: Of course there should be more series, and I like your suggestion of black heavy, white heavy and balanced. My idea way that people should come up with creative transitions from one image to the other and back, I imagined something like the 'powerponit' slide transitions. The images are black and white only for making the challenge somewhat easier.

Comment: I like the restriction to black and white only. I don't necessarily think it makes it easier, but I think restriction is very important for popularity contests otherwise they get too open ended. It might be worth adding more restriction otherwise it risks being closed as too broad. For example, you might restrict how much difference there can be from one frame to the next. Maybe only 5% of pixels can change each frame (or whatever percentage you feel is best). You might feel that particular restriction detracts from some potential solutions so that's just an example.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26554/dither-a-grayscale-image) might have some useful code for creating nice dithered images for your sample images. It converts greyscale to strictly only black and white.

Comment: It might be worth thinking up a few examples of transition effects and then adding restrictions that don't rule out any of the effects you thought of. To make it an interesting challenge but without losing potential answers.

Comment: For example, the effect of paint running down from the top of the picture overwriting the old picture with the new.

Comment: Or a simple slide across (with or without the old image moving too).

Comment: Or "burn through" from a hole appearing in the centre, like old cinema projectors if left on one frame too long.

Comment: Cf http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33172/194 , although the morphs there don't preserve the number of pixels of each colour in the intermediate frames. At present I would vote to close this as too broad, and suggest adding a restriction that in each frame the changed pixels must pair up into adjacent pairs which swap with each other.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was aware of that challenge (I did even participate=), but I did not realize that this one would be so similar to the other one. I really like your idea of the swapping restriction, but I am not sure whether this is perhaps too restrictive. Another idea I had (very vague so far) is considering the white pixels as some kind of 'fluid' that can only move with a certain velocity (or another property) and your suggestion would really match that idea. The question is for each frame transition, should we limit the number of swaps? Or the number of swaps per pixel?

Answer (score 1):

## Catch the robber

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)

*This is my first time making a KOTH. I (mostly) will not post this KoTH. Read the [ReadMe](https://github.com/Cool-Guy1999/Catch-the-Robber/blob/master/README.md) file for more info.*

---

## Overview

A cop spots a robber and the robber runs and ends up in a basement. The cop then goes into the basement and locks the door.

## Gameplay

The basement consist of 49 rooms with dimensions 7 x 7. The top-left room has coordinates `[0,0]` while the bottom-right room has coordinates `[6,6]`. The cop starts on the room with coordinates `[6,3]` while the robber starts on the room with coordinates `[0,3]`.

**Cop**

The cop moves first. The cop can move in one of these directions:

- Up
- Right
- Down
- Left
- Here

The direction *here* indicates that the cop will stay in the current room and will not move. The rest of the directions are self-explanatory. The cop can move in a particular direction if it is a valid one, i.e, the cop cannot move out of the grid or move into a room with a trap.

The cop can also put traps in a room. At the start of every match, the cop has 3 traps. Once a trap has been placed, the cop will not be able to move into the room where the trap is placed.

The cop also has 3 pressure sensors at the start of every match. The cop can move into a room where a pressure sensor has been placed.

If the robber moves into an adjacent room of the cop, the cop will be alerted.

**Robber**

The robber can move in the same directions as the cop does. The robber too cannot move outside the grid.

The robber has two TrapDetector5000 which can be used by the robber. It will detect if there is a trap in one of the adjacent rooms that the robber is in.

If the cop moves into an adjacent room of the robber, the robber will be alerted.

**Goal**

The cop must catch the robber as soon as possible. This can be done by moving into a room where the robber is. The cop will also catch the robber if the robber moves into the room where the cop is.

If the robber moves into a room where the cop has placed a trap or a pressure sensor, the cop will be alerted and the robber will not be able to move for 2 turns, if the room had a trap. However, the robber will be able to move if the room had a pressure sensor.

The robber will be alerted if the robber steps into a room with a pressure sensor.

## Controller

The controller is written in java and can be found [here](https://github.com/Cool-Guy1999/Catch-the-Robber). As a cop or a robber you each have to each complete implement a Java class.

You have to implement the `Cop` interface if you are writing a Cop Bot and implement the `Robber` interface if you are writing a Robber Bot.

There is an `enum direction` with 5 directions `Here, Up, Right, Down, Left` which you can use when building your Bot.

You can use the `Grid.isValidMove(direction)` to check if that direction is a valid move. This is for Cops.

You can use the `Grid.isValidPosition(direction)` to check if that direction is a valid move. This is for Robbers.

You also may write additional functions within that class. The controller comes with one working example of a simple cop and robber bot.

Please use java 7 and please do not exploit stuff in the controller and cheat.

Note that your bot needs to return an `int` from `takeTurn` within 200 milliseconds. Failure to do so will result in the disqualification of your Bot.

## Scoring

Each cop plays 10 rounds against each robber and the number of moves each robber makes in each round will be added up and this is the score of that particular robber. The same goes for cops.

The robber with the highest score and the cop with the lowest score wins!

Comment: This KoTH has potential, I believe.  I might expand the room to ensure that traps aren't an insta-catch.  Also, if a cop moves into a room next to a robber, only the robber knows? (and vice versa)?  If that is true, its going to hard to beat the robber strategy of "stand until a cop moves next to you"

Comment: First of all. Thanks for reviewing this KoTH. What size should the grid be? And "_if a cop moves into a room next to a robber, only the robber knows? (and vice versa)?_" -- Yes. Because this is different from those KoTHs where a turn means movement of both the players. Any idea for making it more interesting?

Comment: I'd say that a 7x7 would be sufficient.  If I am caught in the center, it is still possible that the cop won't catch me if he is on the edge of the room.  I'm not sure how to make it more interesting, but an idea I had would be to allow both the cop and robber to place "pressure sensors" instead of traps.  Their party is informed when stepped on, but they don't know which sensor has been stepped on (unless there is only 1 they placed)

Comment: "_Their party is informed when stepped on_" -- Party? There is just one cop. Should there be more than one cop?

Comment: No.  I just used party to refer to either cop or robber depending on who placed it.

Comment: I was thinking of cops having 2 traps + 4(?) pressure sensors. Also, I've been thinking of giving robbers something... like a dummy (moves in a straight direction and tricks the cops will be alerted if it is in an adjacent room) or one trap-detector-5000 (which detects if there if there is a trap in an adjacent room and can be used only once). What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure about the dummy idea.  I think that this challenge is about calculating probabilities of the enemy's location.  I'd personally would prefer abilities to be purely knowledge granting, but that's my opinion.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I've written some code, but I don't think I'll post this. See the answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

## *Half-finished Idea:*

## Diffusion Battle

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

### Overview

**Players are all present on a toroidal grid. Each player has 16 particles to start with. The total number of particles is fixed but they can change colour. Each turn a player decides what type of action to take for each particle of their colour, but cannot control the direction, which is always random.**

**All players' particles then move in a random direction at the same time, possibly resulting in some of them changing colour. The player with the most particles of their colour at the end of the game is the winner.**

---

### Action types

A player chooses from the following actions for each particle:

- Drift: do not attempt to change the colour of other particles
- Eat: attempt to change the colour of other particles

Each of these actions is applied after all players' particles have aimed in a random direction. This may result in two particles aiming for the same cell. No cell will end up with more than one particle, but aiming for the same cell results in interaction, with no movement and the following rules being applied:

- If both particles chose Drift, nothing happens.
- If both particles chose Eat, nothing happens.
- If one particle chose Eat, the particle that chose Drift will become the colour of the particle that chose Eat.

Clearly choosing Eat is always an advantage when two particles aim for the same destination. However, if a particle aims for a cell that no other particle is aiming for, it will move there, with the following rules being applied:

- If the particle chose Drift it will move with no change.
- If the particle chose Eat it will move and take on a random colour (which may be its own colour or that of any other player).

#### N particles colliding

The case where N particles are all aiming for the same destination cell is a generalisation of the case for 2 particles. None of them will move to the destination cell and the following rules will be applied:

- If all of the N particles chose Drift, nothing happens.
- If all of the N particles chose Eat, nothing happens.
- If some chose Drift and some chose Eat, none will move and all those that chose Drift will change to a colour chosen randomly from those exhibited by those that chose Eat. If there is more than one particle of a given colour that chose Eat, that colour will have a correspondingly higher probability of being chosen.

When N = 2 this reduces to the case described for 2 particles.

It follows that if the N particles are of the same colour, then regardless of their individual choices none will move and they will all remain the same colour.

#### Collision with a particle that was unable to move

What happens to particles that were aiming for an empty cell but the cell is not empty because its occupant was unable to move?

---

## Sandbox thoughts

EITHER

- ALL THOSE THAT AIMED FOR THE SAME CELL AFFECT EACH OTHER

OR

- THOSE THAT AIMED FOR THE SAME CELL DO NOT MOVE, ALL THOSE THAT END UP ADJACENT AFFECT EACH OTHER

I favour the second but I need to consider how it would work with large numbers of particles adjacent.

- Zgarb pointed out in chat that it would be better to have a small probability of changing if failing to eat, so that the penalty for failure is not so extreme. I'm likely to use this as it is fine tunable.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the last question asking for the masses of the elements, this challenge will be slightly more specific. In this challenge, you will find the molar mass of a sequence of amino acid peptides.

Amino acids, of which there are 21, are the units that combine into chains and then bend and change shape to form proteins, which serve widely varying functions in cells and in the body of most all living organisms. Scientists working with peptides, such as chemists and doctors, can easily synthesize a desired peptide chain in the lab thanks to the powers of modern technology. After some purifying and such, he will have the desired sequence in the form of a white powder/crystal like substance.

However, this is science! This means that he will eventually need to weigh out a desired amount of his sequence to perform some reactions or tests. To do this, he needs to know its molar mass.

Today, we know that there are 21 amino acids, and we have found their molar masses and given them names and symbols, just like the 118 elements on the periodic table. They are as follows:

```
Name           Symbol   Molar Mass
Alanine         A        89 
Cysteine        C        121
Aspartic acid   D        133
Glutamic acid   E        147
Phenylalanine   F        165
Glycine         G        75 
Histidine       H        155
Isoleucine      I        131
Lysine          K        146
Leucine         L        131
Methionine      M        149
Asparagine      N        132
Proline         P        115
Glutamine       Q        146
Arginine        R        174
Serine          S        105
Threonine       T        119
Selenocysteine  U        169
Valine          V        117
Tryptophan      W        204
Tyrosine        Y        181
```

**BUT WAIT!!** (how do I make this text bigger?)

#### But wait!!

### But wait!!

## But wait!!

Unlike the elements, the mass of a peptide sequence isn't just the sum of the masses of the constituent amino acids! Amino acids combine in a reaction called a hydrolysis reaction that forms a bond called a peptide bond. Take a look at this diagram:

[image]

A hydrolysis reaction is a reaction in which two large molecules combine to make a larger one, but in the process lose a small molecule. In this case, they lose a water molecule (hence the name hydrolysis). Since the mass of water is 18, when two peptides bond together in a chain they lose 18 molar mass units. So if our sequence was AC (Alanine-Cysteine), the mass would be 89 + 121 - 18 = 192.

**The Challenge**

Your job is to golf a program that computes the molar mass of a given peptide sequence. The sequence will be specified by their one letter symbols, in all caps.

Examples: 
`A` returns 89

`AC` returns 192

`WAGAKRLVLRRE` returns 1453

Shortest byte count wins, no loopholes. Weights must be hardcoded in the program somehow.

Comment: I would estimate a greater than 50% chance that this would be closed as a near-enough dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35599/194 . (Although I thought the same of the elements one, and I was wrong about that).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Do you know how to make the text bigger?

Comment: No. I know how to create headers, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @FarazMasroor "_(how do I make this text bigger?)_" -- You mean as I did in my "mass of elements" post? Select the text you want to format as code and press CTRL+K. Alternatively, add 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: The protein synthesis reaction you show is an example of condensation. Hydrolysis would be the reverse reaction (which incidentally occurs during digestion of proteins.)

Comment: If it's the text "but wait!!" that you wanted to make bigger, I've edited to show the different header text sizes available - just delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: I've also edited to make your table of molar masses a single block (without the white lines running across it). This is just to show you how - click "rollback" from the edit history if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

## Fundamentals of City Planning

In this challenge, you are a city planner.  You have been given an `N` by `M` rectangle to fill with residential lots of size `K` and roads of width `1`.  You know that money is made based on the number of residents in the city, so **your goal is to maximize the number of lots in your rectangle**.  However, the following rules are enforced:

- Roads have a width of 1 square, and all roads must be orthogonally connected to each other.
- Every lot must share at least 1 side with a road
- Lots must all be the same size `K`.  They can be in the shape of any polyomino of size `K`.
- There must be at least 1 road that touches the edge of the rectangle, as your residents need to be able to get in and out!

The winner of the challenge is the one that:

1. Fits the most lots across all of the below examples.  In the case of a tie:
2. Fastest solution, unless multiple answers are running under a second.  In that case:
3. The earliest posted solution

Submitted answers must run in under a minute.

## STDIO

You will be passed three integers, `N`, `M`, `K`.  You need to output the generated grid.  Roads should be represented by `.`.   Lots should be ordered and numbered, and when printed should be represented by their number mod 10.  The ordering can be arbitrary, and is simply used to distinguish lots on output.  Empty squares are allowed and are represented by `#`.

## Test Cases for correctness

Provided solutions can be numbered differently, rotated, and/or reflected

```
1 2 1 
.1

1 3 1
1.2

2 2 1
1.
2.

3 3 1
123
...
456

3 3 2
11#      11.      #11     
2..  or  2..  or  2..
233      233      233
```

## Test cases used for scoring:

```
20 15 1
20 15 2
20 15 3
20 15 4
20 15 5
20 15 6
20 15 7
20 15 8
```

Comment: 1. I got to the bit about lots being the same size `K` and wondered why I would choose `K` to be anything other than `1`. Only when I got to the input spec did I understand. Adding "*of size `K`*" to the end of the second sentence would probably avoid that confusion. 2. Do you have a reference implementation? I'm worried that "fastest solution" might not be a good tiebreaker because on the given test cases the answers may execute in under 200ms.

Comment: I updated, tell me if it looks reasonable?

Comment: Are answers required to be deterministic?

Comment: @trichoplax no, but deterministic will probably lead to better results.  Updated the description.

Answer (score 1):

## Blackjack

### How to Play

Blackjack is for any number of people, but there will be only one in this case. The goal is to get as close to 21 as possible without going over. Aces will be 1 for this program. All other face cards are worth 10.

To start, the player is dealt two cards. They can then choose to hit (take another card) or stand. This repeats until they go over 21 (bust) or decide to stay.

If the player busts, their score is 0. Otherwise, their score is the total of all the cards.

### Input/Output

1. The program should output 2 "cards" (randomly choose between 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, K, Q, J, and A).
2. The player then inputs a move, `stand` or `hit`.
3. If he/she stands, output `Final Score: [total of cards]`.
4. If he/she hits, output another "card". Output `Bust!` if the score is over 21.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the player busts or stands.

### Test Cases

```
Output: 5 K
Input:  hit
Output: 6
Input:  stand
Output: Final Score: 21



Output: A Q
Input:  hit
Output: 7
Input:  hit
Output: 6
Output: Bust!
```

### Rules and Other Notes

- Aces are always 1.
- Each output/input should be on a new line.
- Any trailing spaces and newlines are okay.
- Assume that all input will be valid. You don't need to notify the player of invalid input.
- You cannot read from a file or other source.

### Scoring & Submissions

- This is code golf. Shortest code in **characters** wins.
- How to win: post the shortest working code within one week.
- Please include the language, number of characters, and code. Explanations are appreciated, but not required.

Good luck!

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game), [card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

### Sandbox Questions

Anything I'm forgetting? Does anything need more clarification?

Comment: @TNT code-golf, game, card-games. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

## How to Create a Dating Website

Dating websites make lots of money.  You want lots of money, so you're going to make a dating website.  However, we all know that the most important part of any dating website is the algorithm, so you need to build that first.

When your customers will sign up, they are going to fill out a short survey describing themselves*.  On the survey, they filled out personal interests, personality traits, and other important data for you to process using your algorithm.

Your algorithm must then accept two things:

1. A list of people, where each person has a list of traits
2. A list of trait pairs `(A, B)`, where each pair has a score `S`.  A trait pair matches a couple if one of them has trait `A`, and the other has trait `B`.  The score can be negative.  If `A` and `B` are different, and both people have both of the traits, then the score is doubled.

Your algorithm must then output a list of couples.  Each person must be included in a couple exactly once, and only two people is allowed in each couple**.  Your score is the sum of each couple's score.  A couple's score is the sum of each of the trait pairs they match.

## Input/Output

Input is given as shown in the following example.  Ignore the `# comments`

```
4         # Number of customers
1,3,5,7   # Customer 1's list of traits
1,2,4,5,6 # Customer 2's list of traits
1,6,7     # Customer 3's list of traits
1,2       # Customer 4's list of traits
4         # Number of trait pairs
1,2,-2    # Trait 1 and 2 give a score of -2
1,6,4     # Trait 1 and 6 give a score of 4
2,3,-4    # Trait 2 and 3 give a score of -4
6,6,5     # Trait 6 and 6 give a score of 5
```

Let's say you output:

```
2,3 1,4
```

Then that would match Customer 2 to 3 and 1 to 4.

If we look at `2,3`, they match:

- The first trait pair, because Customer 3 has Trait 1, and Customer 2 has Trait 2
- The second trait pair, because they both have Traits 1 and 6.  (This means double the score)
- The fourth trait pair, because they both have trait 6.  However, because the trait pair only references 1 trait, we don't double the score.

Adding it all up, we get `-2 + 4*2 + 5 = 11`.  The other couple scores `-2 + -4 = -6`, so the final score is `11 + -6  = 5`.

The person who generates the highest scoring pairing wins the challenge.  In the case of a tie, the program that generates it the fastest wins.  If programs are generating the answer in under a second, then the earliest posted answer wins.

**Question: I'm planning on doing 10K people, 500 traits, an average of 50 traits per person, and 5K trait pairs.  I'm doing large numbers because I want efficient algorithms, but I want to know if the numbers are feasible**

<sub>*They clicked a check box saying that they didn't lie, so we know that the survey is accurate</sub>

<sub>**You can assume everybody is a hermaphrodite</sub>

Comment: FYI there's a well-known polynomial-time [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: @feersum, that's for weighted matchings in bipartite graphs. This is maximum weight matching in a complete graph, for which the well-known polynomial-time algorithm is [Edmond's blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). PS Nathan, if you don't want a debate about your cover story, you should probably specify that this dating site is aimed specifically at bisexuals.

Comment: ... or hermaphrodites. Poor snails, perpetually being asked about their gender and not being able to reply "both".

Comment: stdio is a standard header file for input and output functions in the C language. Why is it mentioned in this problem?

Comment: @aditsu STDIO stands for "Standard I/O"

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't change anything I said.

Comment: @aditsu then I don't see your point.  I'm describing how to input/output (and giving an example at the same time)

Comment: My point is STDIO specifically refers to the C header file. What you are then actually showing is example input. If it really was stdio, I would expect some C macros and declarations.

Answer (score 1):

## roll me back a game of hearts

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)

Roll me back a game of hearts
given just a deck of cards
please.

So, I've been playing a game of hearts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts) with three of my friends but I'm not entirely sure if all of them were playing perfectly according to the rules. So I'd like to replay the game with everyone's cards openly visible. And because you like algorithms, you offered me your help determining everyone's cards from the final deck after each hand. However, I can't quite remember if you promised me a full program or just a named function.

A **card** is represented with two characters. The first character represents its value and is one of `23456789TJQKA` (2-10, jack, queen, king, ace). The second character represents its suit and is one of `CDHS` (clubs, diamonds, heards, spades).

The **input** is a list of 52 cards. It can either be a list (array, vector...) of two-character strings or a single space-separated string. You will be given the cards in the exact order they were played. The list represents a valid deck and 2C is the first card in the deck.

**Output** four sets of cards, each representing the starting hand of one player. The first set may correspond to any player but the rest must be ordered in the order of play (so if the first hand to be output is the third one to play, the rest must be in the order of fourth, first, second). The cards in each  player's hand may be output in any order (it's a set). If you choose to output a single string, separate the cards in each hand with spaces and the hands with newlines.

**Game rules:**

Rules irrelevant to this challenge have been formatted in small font

- There are variants for three to six players but the base variant is for four players so let's assume this one.
- <sup>Before the main game each player passes three cards to another player. Since this is a lossy operation, let's just ask for the hands after this passing moment.</sup>
- Each game consists of 13 tricks. Each trick consists of each player in clockwise order playing one card from their hand, then one player "taking" the trick.
- The first trick starts by the two of club. Each subsequent trick is started by whichever player took the previous trick.
- <sup>The first player in a trick can play any card. The first player cannot play hearts unless hearts have already been played in that game or he has no other cards, however. The other players have to play the same suit as the leading player if they have that suit, otherwise they can play any card. Scoring cards cannot be played in the first trick</sup>
- The player that played the highest valued card of the same suit as the leading card of that trick takes that trick. E.G.: in `2C AD KC 5C`, the king of clubs takes the first trick. In `2H KS AS QS` the leading player takes the trick (and fourteen points).
- <sup>The objective of the game is to end up with the fewest points possible. A player gets one point per each hearts taken, and 13 poins for the queen of spades.</sup>

**You may assume** that the deck of cards is valid (exactly one of each card) and that the two of clubs has been lead. You may also assume that the rules concerning the order of play and trick taking have been followed. **You may not assume** the rules concerning which cards can be played when have been followed. Heck, you don't even know that *I* haven't been cheating. Because a player may have been dealt nothing but hearts, you may not even assume only non-scoring cards have been played in the first trick (if everyone on the planet plays 100 games in their life, this may realistically happen to someone).

---

Should I loosen the I/O requirements? How much?
Formatting advice? Which parts (if any) should I trim down? What needs to be clarified?
Anything else?

Comment: So the program you're asking me to write can actually ignore most of the rules of Hearts and I can think purely in terms of a no-trump game in any whist-like game?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Correct. Spades does have trumps, however, and hearts is the only other whist-like game I've played.

Answer (score 1):

## LindenMASM

LindenMASM is an Assembly-like programming language which can be used to generate images from Lindenmayer systems. Lindenmayer systems are very interesting in the fact that they can provide a rudimentary method of generating fractals, such as a Sierpinski triangle. They are also interestingly able to mimic nature very closely for some reason, which can be seen in the below image. You will be implementing a LindenMASM interpreter in a language of your choice.

## Understanding Lindenmayer Systems

You should check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) for a more detailed overview of Lindenmayer systems, as I will simply describe the process of actually using a system. I will be referring to a turtle in this explanation. A turtle is simply the device by which an L-system is drawn. We will use a dragon curve L-system as an example.

Firstly, we need to consider the variables we will be using. In the case of an L-system, a variable is used to control evolution, and does not actually correspond to any movement. We will need two for this, so let's call `X` and `Y` our variables.

Next, we would define our constants. In most L-Systems, the character `F` refers to moving forward, `-` turns left and `+` turns right. We will follow these conventions here, and specify that `-` turns the turtle 90 degrees left and `+` turns the pointer 90 degrees right.

After this, the axiom needs to be defined. This is the starting point of the system, i.e. what it looks like after 0 iterations. In our case, we will set it to `FX`.

Finally, we need to define some rules. Rules are applied by going through each character of the axiom, and if one of them matches a rule, replace it with the defined set of instructions. Our rules are that `X -> X+YF+` and `Y -> -FX-Y`. I will show a quick evolution of steps, so you can see how these rules are applied.

- `n=0` - `FX`
- `n=1` - `FX+YF+`
- `n=2` - `FX+YF++-FX-YF+`
- `n=3` - `FX+YF++-FX-YF++-FX+YF+--FX-YF+`
- `n=4` - `FX+YF++-FX-YF++-FX+YF+--FX-YF++-FX+YF++-FX-YF+--FX+YF+--FX-YF+`

When this is interpreted, however, since `X` and `Y` don't control movement, the interpreted steps for `n=4` would look like this:

`F+F++-F-F++-F+F+--F-F++-F+F++-F-F+--F+F+--F-F+`

Simplified..

`F+F+F-F+F+F-F-F+F+F+F-F-F+F-F-F+`

Which would result in the following drawing:

[image: n=4 Dragon Curve]

## Syntax

There are only a few keywords available in LindenMASM which you will need to implement.

1. `STT` - Begins every LindenMASM file.
2. `AXI $` - Sets the axiom (initial state) of the system.

   - `$` is a series of commands/variables/constants, ranging from the built-ins plus any user-defined functions.
3. `DEG $` - Sets the degree of which all turns will follow.

   - `$` will be a integer or float between 0 and 359, inclusive. The default value is 90 otherwise.
4. `MOV $` - Sets the move distance of which all position adjustments will follow.

   - `$` will be a integer or float between 1 and 100, inclusive. The default value is 10 otherwise.
5. `INC $` - Sets the number of iterations the generation should go through.

   - `$` will be a number between 0 and 30, inclusive. The default value is 0 otherwise. *(a value of 0 means just the axiom is displayed).*
6. `SET $ #` - Sets a constant `$` to a specified command `#`

   - `$` will be a letter between A and Z, inclusive, and will be uppercase.
   - `#` will either be a 0 or a 1, where a 0 corresponds to the constant being one that draws forward, and a 1 corresponds to the constant being one that moves fowards.
7. `RPL $ #` - On every iteration, variable/constant `$` will be replaced with the command/variable/constant string `#`.

   - `$` will be a letter between A and Z, inclusive, and uppercase. It does not need to be `SET` to be replaced.
   - `#` is a string of commands/variables/constants that `$` should be replaced with.
8. `END` - Ends every LindenMASM file.

Each keyword should be placed on a new line. Your program should fail parsing if (a) The file does not start with `STT` or does not end with `END`. Your program should assume that the rest of the keywords will have proper arguments attached to them.

Below is a list of all of the regular commands that cannot be defined by the user:

1. `+` - Rotates the pointer to the right `DEG` degrees.
2. `-` - Rotates the pointer to the left `DEG` degrees.
3. `[` - Saves the pointer's coordinates and heading to a list.
4. `]` - Pops the last value of a list and sets the pointer's coordinates and heading to that.

## Examples

I will give 5 examples, each of which will have detailed information on the pattern, plus a link to have it visualized online.

**Fractal Tree** - `n=6, axiom=X, Θ=25, X->F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X, F->FF` ([Test Online](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/96da72b13af6b1bf736c))

```
STT
AXI X
DEG 25
MOV 10
INC 6
SET F 0
RPL X F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X
RPL F FF
END
```

[image: Fractal Tree]

**Gosper Curve** - `n=4, axiom=F, Θ=60, F->F+G++G-F--FF-G+, G->-F+GG++G+F--F-G` ([Test Online](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/26011af7f84a9fb0bc8f))

```
STT
AXI F
DEG 60
INC 4
SET F 0
SET G 0
RPL F F+G++G-F--FF-G+
RPL G -F+GG++G+F--F-G
END
```

[image: Gosper Curve]

**Koch Variant** - `n=4, axiom=F-F-F-F, Θ=90, F->FF-F--F-F` ([Test Online](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/30de2069b8d234b0f352))

```
STT
INC 4
RPL F FF-F--F-F
SET F 0
AXI F-F-F-F
END
```

[image: Koch Variant]

**Sierpinski Triangle** - `n=7, axiom=F-G-G, Θ=120, F->F-G+F+G-F, G->GG` ([Test Online](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/a1cc46055af2dc261d9c))

```
STT
RPL G GG
RPL F F-G+F+G-F
DEG 120
AXI F-G-G
SET F 0
SET G 0
INC 7
END
```

[image: Sierpinski Triangle]

**Dragon Curve** - `n=12, axiom=FX, =90, X->X+YF+, Y->-FX-Y` ([Test Online](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/71352f591029788c0031))

```
STT
INC 12
DEG 90
AXI FX
SET F 0
RPL X X+YF+
RPL Y -FX-Y
END
```

[image: Dragon Curve]

## Input

Aside from the examples given above, your code should support the following test cases as well:

Input:

```
SET F 0
AXI FF
RPL F F-F+F
END
```

Output: `Error: No STT at beginning.`

Input:

```
STT
SET F 0
AXI FF
RPL F F-F+F
```

Output: `Error: No END at ending.`

## Output

Your program should output the resulting image by outputting an image or by drawing to the screen (e.x. turtle graphics). If you would like to check out a Python 3 example, here is a Github link to [pylasma](http://kade-robertson.github.io/pylasma).

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least number of bytes wins.

Comment: Why is "turtle graphics" in particular mentioned? Why not any other method of drawing to the screen?

Comment: @feersum My intent was to say that, at the time of writing I didn't know how to word it, I was very tired :P

Comment: Do any of the commands accept floating-point arguments?

Comment: @feersum `MOV` and `DEG` are the only two which should support floating-point arguments. I'll update.

Comment: This is pretty close to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9341/194 . The bit that's different is parsing the input, so if you want to make an original question then you could restrict it to validating that a file obeys the structure rules (although I must say that I find "*`$` ... will be one of the variables within `#`*" overly restrictive).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Just my opinion, but validating a text file is much less exciting than the question I'm posing :P I'd rather just scrap this.

Answer (score 1):

## Print time of day using words

I'm not sure if this has been done before. I thought it must have but I could not find one using search. The idea is basically, given a number in seconds, e.g. the output from time(NULL). Return the current time in words using 12 hour clock, e.g.

```
HALF PAST FIVE PM
A QUARTER TO SIX PM
TEN TO SIX PM
SIX O'CLOCK PM
SIX TEN PM
TWELVE NOON
TWELVE O ONE AM
```

Has this challenge been done before?

One thing I cannot decide is when the "PAST" should be used. Should it be used only when there is less than 15 minutes left? Should it be FIVE FIFTY FIVE or FIVE TO SIX?

Comment: It doesn't matter too much which approach you choose as long as you define it clearly so there is no doubt which way is the correct way for your question. I'm guessing using PAST and TO would make it a slightly more challenging/interesting golf.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be a 12 hour clock. As humanly as possible. I think I should add `AM` and `PM` to the answer. Possibly even `NOON`.

Comment: Yes it's a tricky system. Just keep editing to clarify edge cases until the comments stop coming in :)

Comment: This is essentially [It's Spanish Time!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41193) in a different language.

Comment: You have three options. 1. use only the digital times, like FIVE FIFTY FIVE (boring in my opinion) 2. use the word based system, TWENTY TO FIVE (the changeover occurs between 30 and 31 past the hour) 3. use word based system for the 15 minute intervals (half past, quarter past/to and o'clock.) Whatever you do, be very clear about what's required acceptable and what is not. For me 12 noon is PM. If you require NOON you should require MIDNIGHT also. Other things like the  `A` in `A QUARTER` and the `O` in `TWELVE O ONE AM` should be spelt out in detail in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

## Maze to regex

Suppose we have an ASCII maze like so:

```
#######
#s# # #
# # # #
#     #
# ### #
# #  e#
#######
```

The input maze will have the following properties:

- One cell (marked `s`) will denote the start of the maze, and a separate cell (marked `e`) will denote the exit.
- The walls will be denoted by hashes `#`, and empty corridors will be denoted by spaces.
- The maze will be a perfect rectangle, have no cycles, and will consist of exactly one connected component (i.e. all cells will be reachable)

A single character from `NSEW` represents a move North, South, East or West respectively, and consists of moving **two** characters in the specified direction. For instance, the above example is a 3 by 3 maze where the following cells can be occupied:

```
#######
#x#x#x#
# # # #
#x x x#
# ### #
#x#x x#
#######
```

A string consisting of `NSEW` is said to *solve* a maze if applying each move in turn results in the exit being reached at some point in time, regardless of whether the string continues on afterward. If a move is blocked by a wall, the move is ignored and no movement occurs.

Example strings which solve the above maze are `SEES`, `SENSES` and `SSSSSNENNNNNSENNNNNSSSSSSSSWW`.

### The challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which takes in an ASCII maze and outputs a regex. The regex must match a string of `NSEW` if and only if it solves the given input maze.

For instance, all solutions to the 2 by 2 maze

```
#####
#s#e#
# # #
#   #
#####
```

can be encapsulated by the regex

```
^(([NEW]|S[WS]*N)*S[WS]*E([ES]|W[WS]*E)*W[WS]*N)*([NEW]|S[WS]*N)*S[WS]*E([ES]|W[WS]*E)*N[NEWS]*$
```

*([Try it online at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tK5aO4/2))*

### Available features

You may only use the following regular expression features:

```
^$         Start and end anchors respectively
N|E        Alternation
NE         Concatenation
()         Grouping
*          Repetition (0+ times)
+          Repetition (1+ times)
?          Optional (0 or 1 times)
[NESW]     Character classes (but not negated classes)
```

In particular, recursion, wildcards, lookaheads and other unlisted features are not allowed.

---

Sandbox questions:

- What would be better, [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) (scoring by providing a few test mazes, and taking the sum of output regex lengths) or [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (any output regex is okay as long as it is finite and correct)?
- I've chosen this ASCII representation because it looks the nicest, but I'm not sure if it's the most convenient. I'm open to suggestions for alternatives.
- What is the best way to test submissions? I can write a bunch of test cases per maze, but it's impossible for me to test an infinite number of strings.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will never be a wall in a position that permits a move of only 1 step instead of 2? Or should such cases be simply treated as no move possible?

Comment: What range of maze sizes must this work for?

Comment: If you don't have an automated way of checking submissions, you could announce one of "innocent until proven guilty" or "guilty until proven innocent". Either answers require a proof, or answers are assumed to be valid until someone proves otherwise.

Comment: @trichoplax I'll work on the maze definition later, but the input is guaranteed to be valid. Maze size would have to depend on if this is golf (which would probably have a larger limit) or metagolf

Answer (score 1):

## Sorting trains

This problem is based off of a solitaire card game called [Calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculation_(card_game)).  You can play it [here](http://greenfelt.net/calculation) (highly recommended).

You are in charge of designing a [train yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_yard).  At your junction, you have an In/Out track (queues) and Storage (stack).  **Train cars come in a random order; your job is to arrange them into 4 different ordered trains.**  Land is expensive, so we need you to **minimize the amount of storage tracks we need.**

Your [rail car mover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_car_mover) can only handle 1 train at a time, and move a car:

1. In track -> Out track
2. In track -> Storage track
3. Storage track -> Out track.

**Each Out Track needs the same 25 cars, each in a different order:**

```
Track 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,0
Track 2: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,0
Track 3: 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,0
Track 4: 4,8,12,16,20,24,3,7,11,15,19,23,2,6,10,14,18,22,1,5,9,13,17,21,0
```

We can use `(nx+n) mod 25` to calculate ID of the `x`th car of the `n`th track.

#### Important notes:

- Storage tracks can store as many cars as you want, but you can only remove the most recently placed car
- Cars cannot be moved from one storage track to another
- Your algorithm must be deterministic (it must do the same thing given the same input queue and the same number of storage stacks)
- You may get into an impossible situation, where you end up not being able to order the trains.  If that happens, try again with additional storage tracks.

#### Input:

Your input is a list of integers, where each integer is the ID of the train car.

#### Output:

You need to return a list of moves that sorts the cars into the Out tracks.  A move looks like `I->S1` or `S1->O2`, where `I` is the input track, `S#` is a storage track, and `O#` is an output track.

#### Scoring:

Your score is the total number of tracks you need for of all test cases (you can use a different number of tracks for each test case).  Lowest score wins.

#### Test cases:

```
4,13,20,23,22,21,0,18,8,17,16,6,18,22,15,19,21,8,6,24,7,21,9,4,24,19,0,20,12,1,3,10,5,6,19,23,17,9,14,24,13,5,10,15,2,14,7,8,6,10,3,18,22,16,2,4,10,14,1,21,11,9,22,18,20,16,1,4,12,0,12,11,20,11,19,12,0,13,9,11,23,24,15,3,14,5,2,5,8,7,7,3,16,13,15,23,17,1,2,17
1,8,7,5,6,7,21,9,15,5,7,6,21,13,13,18,16,12,22,10,18,14,13,14,10,0,8,24,13,23,2,9,3,4,19,11,24,16,15,10,8,22,3,2,16,17,1,2,12,18,19,2,19,22,0,23,12,24,11,23,23,3,21,15,0,16,14,5,17,10,20,20,0,15,6,7,20,11,17,22,6,17,5,9,1,8,14,21,4,4,3,11,12,4,20,19,1,18,9,24
21,2,14,11,12,21,15,21,16,23,2,19,8,14,23,0,16,4,7,9,24,10,0,11,17,5,4,8,10,0,20,6,5,18,18,6,9,10,22,10,9,1,16,22,1,22,6,17,19,7,2,1,7,18,3,18,11,2,11,7,23,17,6,3,19,13,21,4,20,14,24,20,15,15,15,13,13,12,22,5,13,20,24,3,24,23,4,0,9,8,5,17,16,8,14,12,3,19,1,12
2,7,10,22,15,3,16,7,3,6,4,17,2,20,6,21,13,5,1,7,16,18,24,17,8,14,5,23,17,18,13,0,9,14,24,21,19,23,0,20,15,1,12,24,3,18,11,5,15,7,4,4,9,8,17,12,0,23,6,8,14,12,1,22,9,11,14,20,19,3,12,23,11,19,16,11,22,16,9,4,13,19,1,22,15,2,8,10,0,13,10,18,24,10,21,6,5,2,21,20
14,20,18,21,19,10,7,16,2,22,14,15,17,24,8,10,13,0,11,5,11,11,7,13,19,9,22,10,7,0,3,16,2,8,21,8,4,14,2,19,24,16,12,1,0,0,17,15,1,21,6,5,4,6,12,23,3,15,21,2,12,23,14,23,5,1,10,1,17,13,7,22,4,5,18,6,18,12,16,11,9,13,6,19,23,15,17,22,4,20,8,3,18,20,24,20,9,24,3,9
0,23,4,4,14,17,14,0,8,21,8,9,8,5,16,20,15,9,24,23,12,11,24,2,14,17,3,21,1,19,5,17,15,16,7,2,22,20,6,1,24,16,7,22,21,19,6,13,23,11,4,11,15,19,20,19,18,5,1,18,10,22,16,6,18,20,10,9,6,2,12,23,7,12,3,9,10,7,5,10,13,3,17,12,13,2,1,0,15,4,22,18,11,14,3,24,21,8,0,13
8,19,19,0,23,7,10,21,2,22,13,20,2,10,16,21,3,17,20,18,5,9,14,19,22,0,7,6,3,10,18,6,6,5,24,2,11,24,7,1,11,17,8,9,24,5,15,18,16,24,11,5,14,1,0,13,16,0,13,17,8,12,4,1,21,20,11,10,14,16,8,21,4,7,17,9,13,4,1,3,15,6,22,23,9,23,15,12,15,19,3,20,2,23,12,12,4,18,22,14
17,3,8,24,18,5,7,2,13,2,9,19,21,6,8,8,21,16,17,3,11,20,24,24,12,11,18,11,16,15,24,9,14,10,18,4,22,20,0,10,7,14,6,1,15,6,13,7,3,12,7,23,4,21,0,23,2,10,12,22,9,17,0,4,4,3,22,16,23,20,15,18,10,8,23,1,14,11,5,19,16,1,2,22,9,12,1,5,13,19,14,20,19,5,13,0,15,6,21,17
```

Answer (score 1):

## Be Rational! Finding Rational Roots of Polynomials

---

In this challenge you are to find ***all*** rational zeroes of a polynomial. The results have to be exact. I would suggest using [The Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

### Input

---

Input can be through function argument, command argument, or user input. Input will be a polynomial. The polynomial may have rational coefficients. If a term has a coefficient of zero, that term will not be included in the input. `x^1` will be abbreviated as `x`.

**Examples:**

```
-x^7+4x^4/7-21x^2/2+5x+23/19
...//More to be added when posted
```

### Output

---

Output will be a list of the rational roots of the input polynomial. Output can be through function return value or stdout. If output in string format, you will use improper fractions separated by commas. The output must be simplified as much as possible. Duplicate roots should not be printed more than once.

**Examples:**

```
4/5,2/3,-15/2
...//More to be added when posted.
```

---

### Example Cases

```
> x^2-1
1,-1
...//More to be added when posted.
```

Just like all [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) questions, the answer with the lowest byte count wins.

### Questions:

Is this too much like [Peter's earlier question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/find-real-roots-of-a-polynomial)?
Are there any points I haven't covered or are not clear?
Any grammar/spelling mistakes?
Any tips on improved formatting?

Comment: [Somewhat related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38513/factor-a-polynomial-over-a-finite-field-or-the-integers)

Comment: The title is one character shy of the minimum title length and "abbreviate" should be "abbreviated." Can the roots be listed in any order? Do they have to be fully reduced or could we, for example, use 2/4 in place of 1/2? I would also suggest rewording "fractional coefficients" to "rational coefficients."

Answer (score 1):

## Rec(ursion)less execution

We have a simple (non-Turing complete) language.

Each line of program is a set of terms separated by single space.
Some of terms (ending with `()`) are function calls.
Some lines (whose first term ends with `:`) are function definitions.
The lines that are not function definitions are called expressions.

This is a sample program:

```
funa: one two three
funb: funa() four oclock rock
here we go funb()
```

Here we have two function definition lines and one expression line.

And this is BNF for this language just for clarity:

```
literal ::= [any printable char other than ' ', ':', '(', ')']+
function_header ::= literal ':'
function_call ::= literal '()'
term ::= literal | function_call
expression ::= term | expression_list ' ' term
function_definition ::= function_header expression

program_line ::= function_definition | expression
program ::= [program_line '\n']+
```

The task is to write a program or function that validates the program P and performs `EXECUTE(P)` if the program adheres to validation rules.

Validation rules:

1. `EXECUTE(P)` eventually stops (it's not Turing complete - enough to check if one of the called functions would eventually cause itself to be called - either being recursive itself or "mutually recursive" with other function it calls),
2. while calling `EXECUTE(P) -> EXECUTE_LINE(P,L)`, each function definition search succeedes (in other words - the program will not try to call undefined function).

If program does not pass validation rule 1 or 2, `ERROR: RECURSIVE FUNCTION` or `ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED FUNCTION` should be printed respectively.

When both rules seem to be violated, assume that search for undefined function causes the algorithm to fail (stop) instantly, so recursion that would occur later if the function was found, is not reported. We only report `ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED FUNCTION` in this case (see Example 5 below).

In similar way, if recursion prevents a call to function that would not be found otherwise, even though the function containing call to unrecognized function is called only `ERROR: RECURSIVE FUNCTION` is reported (see Example 4 below).

If validation does not report any of those two errors, `EXECUTE(p)` should be called.

Executing a program is defined like this:

```
EXECUTE(P)
  - for each line L in the program P:
     - if L is not a function definition EXECUTE_LINE(P,L)

EXECUTE_LINE(P,L)
  - for each term T in L:
      - if T is a literal
          print T followed by single space
        else
          FH = T without '()' + ':'
          FDL = find in P a line starting with term FH
          FD = all terms of FDL after FH
          EXECUTE_LINE(FD)
```

Example 1:

```
a: b()
b: a()
c: cucumber
other: nofun()
d: apple banana and c()
we have d()
```

Output:

```
we have apple banana and cucumber
```

Note, that in spite of existence of mutually recursive function definitions `a` and `b` and function definition `other` calling undefined function `nofun` error was not raised, because execution never goes to any to this functions.

Example 2:

```
other: nofun()
c: apple banana and cucumber
we have other()
```

Output:

```
ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED FUNCTION
```

Example 3:

```
a: b()
b: a()
c: apple banana and cucumber
we have b()
```

Output:

```
ERROR: RECURSIVE FUNCTION
```

Example 4:

```
a(): a() nofun()
hello a()
```

Output:

```
ERROR: RECURSIVE FUNCTION
```

We don't output `ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED FUNCTION`, because the program would never try to execute `nofun`, recurring infinitely into first term of definition of `a`.

Example 5.

```
a(): nofun() a()
hello a()
```

Output:

```
ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED FUNCTION
```

We don't output `ERROR: RECURSIVE FUNCTION` here, because the program would fail to find definition for `nofun` before even tring to recurse into `a`.

**Accepted solution**:
a function or a program that takes a program in the above-defined language, validates and runs it.
*You can assume that program has already been split into single lines*, however you can use raw input or accept program as single string when convenient.

This is code-golf, so the shortest submission in term of bytes will win.
However, all working submissions in all languages will be appreciated.

Comment: The two rules seem to be inconsistent: the first one prohibits the recursive function `f: f()` even if `f` isn't called; and the second prohibits the function which calls an undefined function `f: fail()`, but only if `f` is called. It would be less confusing to make them both syntactic (based on the text of `P`) or both semantic (based on the execution of `P`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I didn't mean to prohibit existence of recursive functions that are not called, this was my description that was not precise enough. I clarified the description and added some more examples. So now, both rules are based on execution of `P` rather than text of `P`.

Answer (score 1):

## Golf a game of Nim

Similar to my previous [Write the shortest game of Alak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48388/38891) challenge, this time you have to golf another simple game - [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

You may already know how to play, but if you don't, here are the rules:

- In Nim, two players take turns removing objects from heaps (piles).
- Each turn, one player removes at least one object from any heap.
- You can take as many objects as you want, provided they all come from the same heap.
- You can take from any heap you want, but you can't take objects from two different heaps in the same move.
- The player to take the last piece(s) wins.

There are 3 heaps, each starting out with a random number of objects between 2 and 20.

**Input**

Input is in the form of two numbers - a heap number and the number of objects to take from that heap.
For example, the input `1 2` means "take 2 objects from heap #1".

**Output**

Every turn, the program must print to STDOUT (or your language's closest alternative) the amount of objects in each heap. (This includes at the start of the game.)
For example, if there were 5 objects in heap #1, 2 objects in heap #2, and 0 objects in heap #3, you would output this:
`5 2 0`
When one player wins by taking the last piece(s), you have to output `P# wins` and end the game, where # is the number of the player who won (1 or 2.)

**Assumptions**

- Input will always be in the form of `Heap# Amount`. Any invalid input can be handled however you like.
- The input will never ask to take from a heap that doesn't exist, or take more objects than a heap contains.

## Questions for Meta

- Are there any loopholes?
- Should the sizes of each heap be set, rather than random?
- Should there be a random number of heaps?
- Should programs have to handle taking objects from non-existent heaps, or more objects that a heap has?
- I'm 99% certain I've covered everything, but have I left out any rules of Nim?

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired, but I don't see any specification for how the initial sizes of the heaps are set. With respect to your questions, personally I think the rules of Nim are trivial; and that it's if not standard then at least typical for interactive [tag:code-golf] to not require handling bad inputs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, I've added that to the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Triple Triad Tournament! [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

*(anything in italic parenthesis is a note for the sandbox)*

### About Triple Triad

Triple Triad is a card game from the Final Fantasy series. I've never played a FF game that included it, though, so I'm only familiar with [the version](http://wiki.p-insurgence.com/Triple_Triad) in the Pokémon fangame *Pokémon Insurgence*. It may or may not be different than the original version, so apologies in advance if this isn't quite what you're expecting. :)

In Triple Triad, each card has 4 numerical stats that range from 1 to 10*: An "up" value, a "left" value, a "right" value, and a "down" value. Here's an example of a card with an "up" value of 1, a "left" value of 6, a "right" value of 3 and a "down" value of 2:

[image]

### Triple Triad Rules

At the beginning of each game, players construct a "deck" of five cards, chosen from their entire collection. These cards are kept secret from the other player.

Triple Triad is played on a 3x3 grid. Players take turns choosing a card from their deck and placing it on an empty square of the grid. The goal of the game is to control the majority of the cards when the grid is filled. When the game is complete, one card is randomly selected from the loser's deck and given to the winner.

#### Control

When a card is placed on the grid, it is controlled by its owner. In order to come out of the game victorious, you must gain control of cards that the opponent played.

To gain control of an opponent's card, you must place a card of your own that "beats" it adjacent (not including diagonals) to the card you want to take control of. Whether or not your card beats the opponent's depends on their stats and which side you place your card on.

Imagine this board as the current game state and the blue card as a card in my deck:

[image]

If I want to take control of the opponent's Numel, I have to place my Mareep adjacent to it. This leaves only two options: The top middle square or the middle right square. If I were to place it on the top middle square, my card would be to the left of the opponent's. As a result, Mareep's "right" value of 2 would be contested against Numel's "left" value of 4. 2 is not greater than 4, so my opponent would retain control of Numel. Note that my value must be strictly greater; a tie would be the same as a loss.

If I were to place my card in the middle right corner, it would be below the opponent's card. As a result, Mareep's "up" value of 4 would be contested against Numel's "down" value of 3. 4 is greater than 3, so I would gain control of Numel (which would turn blue to indicate that).

This process is applied in all four directions at once. If there was a card below Mareep with an "up" value of 1 or 2, I would gain control of it as well. However, gaining control is not done passively or recursively. Control can only be contested at the exact moment a card is placed, and gaining control of a card does not count as "placing it".

### Tournament Rules

Each bot is given a budget of [image]*(TBD)* with which to purchase cards before the tournament (this will be done by the author, not the bot itself, and will be hardcoded into the bot). Here are the cards, along with their costs:

```
There - 1000
 will - 1500
   be - 1500
    a - 2500
 list - 3000
 here - 4000
```

The bots will play in a Round Robin tournament with Bo3 matches *(subject to change. not sure if round robin will work well or if i should be using Bo5 or what)*. The bot that wins the most matches will be declared the winner.

#### Match Procedure

1. Each bot chooses 5 cards from their collection to create a deck. (If they have less than five cards, they forfeit the match.)
2. The game is played as described above, until the board is filled. *(i'm not sure how to decide who should go first. alternate? winner of the last game? loser?)*
3. When the game is complete, a random card from the loser's deck is removed from their collection and inserted into the winner's collection. (At the end of the match, each bot's collection is reset to its original state.) *(i'm not totally sure about choosing a random card. it's how the original game works, but it's not necessarily 100% fair. the idea is that over the course of a round robin tournament, any RNG variance will be smoothed out, but i don't know...)*
4. Repeat steps 1 through 3 until one bot has won 2 games.

### Input / Output Specifications and Controller Details

*(none yet lmao)*

---

<sup>* The *Insurgence* variant has some nonsense regarding Pokémon types at higher difficulty levels, but this challenge will ignore that.</sup>

Comment: Your mention of excluding recursive moves makes me wonder what the game would be like including recursion, on a much larger board... (perhaps as a separate KotH)

Comment: Choosing a random card for the winner will introduce unfair variation in a single round robin, but I think that's worth it for the increased variety of games that will test strategies more thoroughly. As long as you don't mind running the round robin multiple times until it converges on a fair score, I would keep the random element.

Answer (score 1):

## Sudoku with handicap

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

> **Note:** I've completely reworked this, as the comments convinced me that there's not a good way to describe the restrictions I originally was after in a language-independent way without unreasonably restricting languages. Thanks to all the commenters.
>
> I now reworked the question in a way that also inhibits traditional recursive solving (at least doing so in a straightforward way), and at the same time even allows to add a metrics about the "efficiency" of the algorithm. The basic idea being that your program is called not once, but many times, each time only having limited information about the field.
>
> Also note that this new version requires me to write a driver program; so the question cannot go live until the driver program is written.

*Questions are set in italics inside the text*

The goal of this challenge is to solve a given Sudoku. However there's a twist:  The program cannot access the full board at any time. Instead it is called repeatedly, and each time it has only limited information about the board. I'll refer to the totality of all calls as the "calling loop". The program can then request different information for the next run, or declare that it is finished (that is, request to not be called again; the call loop is terminated).

The only way to pass information between different runs is through the Sudoku board, and a small amount of scratch space. The Sudoku board is initialized before the first call with the Sudoku to solve (obviously) and is then checked after the call loop terminated. During the call loop, the Sudoku board is not checked, so you may "abuse" it to store additional information, as long as at the end, a valid result is generated.

Since it may not be possible to completely solve all Sudokus using such an algorithm, the only hard requirement is that the call loop is guaranteed to eventually terminate, the Sudoku field after termination is in a valid state. The rest is covered by scoring.

Standard loopholes are explicitly disallowed.

## The stored data

The data that is stored outside the program consists of 90 nine-it unsigned numerical values (that is, minimal nmumber 0, maximal number 511), 81 of which represent the Sudoku field, and 9 values are scratch space. The values of the field are interpreted as bit fields, as described below.

In the following I'll use as example the Sudoku field

```
4.5|.7.|89.
..2|.5.|6..
..7|9..|542
---+---+---
..3|5.6|489
...|3.8|...
684|7.9|1..
---+---+---
238|..5|9..
..6|.9.|3..
.79|.3.|2.1
```

where dots contain fields that have not been filled.

Initially, the data gets filled as follows:

- Each field pre-filled with number $n$ is represented by the value $2^{n-1}$, that is, the bit corresponding to that number is set, and all other bits are unset.
- The unfilled fields are represented by the value $511$ (that is, all nine bits are set).
- The scratch space is filled with $0$.

After the run loop terminates, each pre-filled field needs to have the same value as initially, and each initially empty field must have *at least* the bit corresponding to the correct solution set. That is, every zero bit represents a value that your program excluded for that field, and a program that excludes the correct solution is disqualified.

The contents of the field is only evaluated at the end of the call loop. So in between your program is free to make creative use of the storage space given.

## The input

The program receives its data through standard input of the following form:

The first line contains a description of which data is given to/set by the program in this run. It consists of one to three space-separated words from the following list. On the first run, it is just "S". At later runs, it is exactly what the program requested at its previous run.

The possible values and corresponding interpretation are:

- `R1` to `R9`: The indicated row of the Sudoku, `1` being the uppermost row.
- `C1` to `C9`: The indicated column of the Sudoku, `1` being the leftmost column.
- `F1` to `F9`: The indicated $3\times 3$ subfield of the Sudoku, numbered left to right, up to down. So for example `1` denotes the upper left subfield, `6` denotes the middle right subfield.
- `S`: The scratch space.

The next one to three lines contain the corresponding data, from left to right, and from up to down, as space separated decimal numbers.

So at the first run, your program will receive the input

```
S
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

At the second run with the example Sudoku field, the input to your program might be:

```
R2 C3 F4
511 511 2 511 16 511 32 511 511
16 2 64 4 511 8 128 32 256
511 511 4 511 511 511 32 128 8
```

## Output

The first one to three lines are the new values to replace the ones given in the input. The number of the lines must be the same as the number of fields in the first input line, and each line must contain nine values separated by whitespace (leading/trailing whitespace gets ignored).

If some field appears in more than one data line, the corresponding values are bitwise anded together. For example, if the initial line of your program's input was

```
R1 C1
```

and the first two line of your output read (with question marks replacing values that are irrelevant for this example — of course your code may not actually output question marks here)

```
3 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
5 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

then the upper left value us the Sudoku storage field will be `3 & 5`, that is, `1`

Following those data lines, there will be a single line containing either the single word `STOP`, in which case the run loop is terminated and the resulting field is created, or a line containing one to three whitespace separated words requesting data to be served in the next run, that is, the words to be presented in the first line of the next run of the program.

## Scoring:

The score for qualifying entries is calculated as follows (lower score is better):

- You get 1 score point for each run of your program.
- You get 5 score points for each set bit in the final representation of your Sudoku field
- At the end, subtract 45 (because a perfectly solved Sudoku will have nine bits set; if your program leaves less bits set, it will be disqualified anyway).

The total score is then calculated as weighted mean of the test cases, where the difficulty is used as weight, rounded up to the next integer. That is, if $d_k$ is the difficulty assigned to test case $k$, and $S_k$ is the score you achieved at test case $k$, your total score is
$$S = \left\lceil \frac{\sum_k d_k S_k}{\sum_k d_k}\right\rceil$$

*Sandbox question: Should I change the relative weight of program runs versus unsolved fields? And is the difficulty weighting a good idea, or should I simply add up all scores?*

## Test cases:

(Hardness as reported by GNOME Sudoku)

**Test case 1:** Easy (0.17)

```
4.5|.7.|89.
..2|.5.|6..
..7|9..|542
---+---+---
..3|5.6|489
...|3.8|...
684|7.9|1..
---+---+---
238|..5|9..
..6|.9.|3..
.79|.3.|2.1
```

Solution:

```
415|672|893
892|453|617
367|981|542
---+---+---
723|516|489
951|348|726
684|729|135
---+---+---
238|165|974
146|297|358
579|834|261
```

**Test case 2:** Hard (0.63)

```
.6.|52.|..8
7..|...|9.2
.82|71.|56.
---+---+---
.59|...|..6
.76|...|14.
8..|...|72.
---+---+---
.18|.36|25.
6.3|...|..1
5..|.41|.9.
```

Solution:

```
961|524|378
745|683|912
382|719|564
---+---+---
159|472|836
276|398|145
834|165|729
---+---+---
418|936|257
693|257|481
527|841|693
```

**Test case 3:** Very hard (0.96)

```
.35|.94|...
..8|.53|..9
4..|8..|...
---+---+---
..1|9..|.85
..9|1.5|3..
54.|..8|9..
---+---+---
...|..7|..1
6..|58.|7..
...|41.|82.
```

Solution

```
135|294|678
268|753|149
497|861|532
---+---+---
371|946|285
829|175|364
546|328|917
---+---+---
982|637|451
614|582|793
753|419|826
```

*Sandbox question: Should I add more test cases?*

Comment: Pretty sure you meant code golf not gode golf.

Comment: Is using constraint programming libraries/capabilities of a language allowed, since I'm only calling them and not writing them?

Comment: Also do you intend to add a time limit constraint to the challenge? I could write an answer that tries every possible grid until one is valid, without recursion or stacks

Comment: @muddyfish: Definitely. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Fatalize: I don't know constrained programming libraries; it might be something I also want to ban. Maybe ban every built-in library that could not be written without recursion? Also, good point on the brute force method. I don't really like time limits, because they are too vague (different computers have different speed), maybe limitations on loops would be an alternative. Or limitations on how often the same variable/memory location may be changed.

Comment: Limitations on how often a variable can change would be useless in python because you can `setattr` globals.

Comment: @muddyfish: `setattr` also changes a variable (by adding attributes to it), doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but if you're saying you can't do that, you're saying you can only have a certain number of variables.

Comment: I really don't know what's banned as a recursive technique. For instance, what is a stack data structures? Can I use a list and extract the last element? What if I used dynamic programming instead of recursion?

Comment: Are stack-based languages (CJam, GolfScript, PostScript, FORTH, etc) banned? If so, are languages which use a stack for function/method calls (C, Java, etc.) also banned? Would a better approach be to forget talking about stacks and instead allow only a certain number of memory locations to be used, and limit each of them to 8-bit values? Then C-like language programmers can use a single global array for all their memory, or split it between a few global arrays and some loop variables; stack-based language programmers can work with a limited maximum stack depth; etc.

Comment: Basically what I want to prevent is algorithms trying to insert some numbers, and when it fails, track back and try something different.

Answer (score 1):

## Is a point inside a polygon?

Given the polygon with 2 < *N* < 11 sides, on 2D plane, find out if a given point is inside the polygon.

The input can be an array of points in `x`, `y`, each determining a vertex, or by a string in format `X Y x1 y1 x2 y2 ... xN yN` (you may choose other separator). The `X` and `Y` are the coordinates of the point to be tested. The list then contains `N` verices, and the last point is connected to the first point. All `x` and `y` are integers.

Using any built-in functions performing the test is prohibited (like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains%28java.awt.Point%29))

You should consider that a point is inside a polygon also when it is one of its vertices or it lies on one of its edges.

## Notes

1. Tags would be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [code-restrictions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-restrictions)
2. Should max `x` and `y` be determined?
3. Should they be positive (`uint`) values only?
4. Some questions of this type have already been asked on StackOverflow ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11716268/2088851), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test?lq=1)). Is it ok to ask this question here? (I didn't find it)
5. Should the question also allow non-convex polygons? A non-convex (concave) is a polygon which has at least one of its angles larger than 180 deg., and can borders intersect? (I think it can be too complicated and in my opinion it should be for convex polygons only).

Comment: The question should definitely allow non-convex polygons, but if it allows self-intersection then you'll need to pick a winding rule and explain how it works.

Comment: Be aware that some of the answers [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32898/20260) generalize to polygons.

Answer (score 1):

## <s>Literal Fourier Transform (or Fouriest Numbers?)</s> [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10608/convert-number-to-a-base-where-its-representation-has-most-4s)

(*inspired by [this Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal comic](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2874)*)

> It's called a fourier tranform when you take a number and convert it to the base system where it will have more fours, thus making it "fourier". If you pick the base with the most fours, the number is said to be "fouriest."

**Goal: Given a positive integer `n` in base 10:**

$$
4 \le n_{10} \le 2^{31} -1
$$

**Write a function that displays its equivalent in another base in the format below that maximizes the number of `4`s, i.e. the *fouriest*:**

```
Base x; Fouriest y
```

Notes:

1. If multiple bases tie on the number of `4`s, any base will be accepted. E.g. if the input has the *fouriest* value already, it's fine to return/display the input.
2. Numbers may not necessary yield a `4`, see last example below.

Examples:

- (from comic) `624 -> Base 5; Fouriest 4444`
- `2316780 -> Base 14; Fouriest 444444`
- `4 -> Base 10; Fouriest 4`
- `5 -> Base 10; Fouriest 5`

*Bonus:*

1. Have your function accept a second argument `m` for the input base: 1/4 reduction in submission size.

*Winning:*

Shortest code in bytes wins.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: If two different bases give the same number of 4s, can either be chosen?

Comment: @trichoplax yes, I think that'll be an extension of point 1 under "Notes". :)

Comment: I'm not personally a fan of bonuses (I prefer just one well defined objective), but if you choose to have a bonus it might work better to make it a percentage reduction instead of a number of bytes. Otherwise the bonus has very different effect on different languages.

Comment: P.S. With or without a bonus, I think this is a brilliant challenge.

Comment: @trichoplax along the lines of everything-to-do-with-four, I was thinking of shaving 1/4 for the bonus component, but then I'm not too sure if that's too much. :p I guess I can still consider that... while awaiting for other suggestions. :D

Comment: [Dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10608/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks for pointing that out! I wouldn't be posting this then. It didn't mention "fourier", which explains why it slipped through my search for posted questions.

Answer (score 1):

### Find all matchings [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

Golf [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32438350) in any language. Fewest bytes wins.

---

Given two equal-size sets of positive integers,

```
A={3,1,5}
B={2,4,3}
```

a matching pairs up elements from each set, like:

```
{(5, 2), (1, 4), (3, 3)}
```

There's one matching for each permutation of `n` elements, where `n` is the size. Your goal is to print or return all the matchings.

```
{(3, 2), (1, 4), (5, 3)}
{(3, 2), (1, 3), (5, 4)}
{(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 3)}
{(1, 2), (5, 4), (3, 3)}
{(5, 2), (3, 3), (1, 4)}
{(3, 4), (1, 3), (5, 2)}
```

**Input:** Two nonempty equal-size collections (lists, arrays, sets) of positive integers. Numbers won't repeat within a collection, but may overlap between them. If your collection is ordered, you may assume it to be sorted.

**Output:** Print or return all possible matchings.

Each matchings must appear exactly once, in any order. They must be somehow grouped or separated, so you can tell where each one beings and ends. These rules also apply to the pairs in each matching.

**Banned:** Built-ins that generate matchings or permutations.

Answer (score 1):

## Blastoff

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Your goal is the create the following text output:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Blastoff!
```

The "`10` " will be generated by the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("10 ");}
```

The "`9` " will then be generated by a function in a different language of your choice; the "`8` " by a function in a different language; and so on until the last function generates "`Blastoff!`".  Each function will take as input the complete source code of the previous step in the form of a string and output the next number in the sequence and a space (or the string "Blastoff!").

Each function must "do something meaningful" with the input.   Doing something meaningful is defined to mean that the output will vary based on the input.  That is, ignoring the input or trivially using it (e.g. making it evaluate as 0 no matter what comes in and then adding the needed number) fails to meet the challenge.

## Scoring

A contestants base score will be the sub-total of the byte-length of all 10 functions.  To encourage creativity, the base score will then be divided by the number of different techniques used to generate the output.  For example, "string splitting", "character count", "bitwise and", etc.  The technique of each function is defined as first thing done to the input string other than assignment to a variable.

## Example

The following Perl code illustrates how a "`9` " can be generated:

```
nine('#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("10 ");}');

sub nine{
 @a=split(/"/,$_[0]);
 print $a[1]-1 ." ";
}
```

Here, the function nine() takes the source code of the C program and manipulates it to get the number 9, then adds a space to the printed output.  For scoring purposes, only the subroutine counts - the additional code was added for illustration purposes only and need not be listed on an entry in general.  The input string for the next function will start with the "s" in "sub" and go through the final "}"

The score for this function is thus 54 (including the actually unnecessary CRs and spaces).  The technique used here is string splitting.  An entry that included this code would thus look like this:

### 9: Perl

```
sub nine{
 @a=split(/"/,$_[0]);
 print $a[1]-1 ." ";
}
```

**Score:** 54

**Technique:** String split

### 8: Ruby

...

### Total

**Base score:** (54 + ... ) = 512

**Unique techniques:** 8

**Final score:** (512 / 8) = 64

---

Meta comments:

- The goal of the rules is to 1) avoid trivial solutions and 2) encourage thinking about the next step while writing the current one.  If the rules need to be added to enhance either aim, let me know.
- Is ten functions too many?  I could start the count at 5 if that seems better

Comment: I think 10 is good, as it encourages users to be ever more creative with each function.

Comment: "Doing something meaningful" is *very* hard to make precise.

Comment: @Peter I defined it as having variable output based on the input.  While something as simple as an if statement will cause that to happen, I think it might be OK when combined with the incentive for different techniques - 10 trivial "if input >=< something" routines won't be a very good score anyway as all techniques will be "comparison".  Of course I'm open to better wording suggestions. :)

Comment: @ThaddeusB Great idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for a challenge but I'm not sure if it would be best as a [popularity-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-challenge) or [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), I'm also not sure what rules I should apply to make it more interesting.

---

### **"Convert an image to LEGO safe-colours"**

The task is to convert the existing colours from a JPEG image into LEGO-safe colours.

### What are LEGO-Safe colours?

For the purpose of this challenge, LEGO-Safe colours are defined as the [seven oldest solid colours produced by LEGO](https://www.flickr.com/photos/126975831@N07/15801189140) that are still in production. (The exception being grey which has changed in recent years, for the purpose of this challenge, the original grey will be used).

The colours are hexadecimal approximations from [this](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/colorguide.cgi) list.

```
White, #f2f3f2
Grey, #a1a5a2
Black, #000000
Bright Red, #c4281b
Bright Yellow, #f5cd2f
Dark Green, #287f46
Bright Blue, #0d69ab
```

### Images

You may demonstrate your results using images provided by yourself or the ones shown below.

**Lego Factory (Colour)**

[image]

**Lego and Duplo Bricks (Greyscale)**

[image]

Comment: [Dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50314/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Bummer

Answer (score 1):

## Another cake question - Share it fairly!

I'm having a party, and there were going to be 8 of us. As I like to cut the slices of cake fairly, I normally get a round cake and make the cuts with the help of a protractor (any code golfer would!) But this time I found the bakery were making octagonal cakes, so I bought one of these to help me with my cutting.

The problem is, now there are only 7 of us! Some people are *so* inconsiderate, dropping out at the last minute! How am I going to cut the cake fairly now?

Well it turns out that at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18244/4768 they have the answer. Although my protractor is no good, it's still true that if I start my cuts at evenly spaced points on the perimeter of the cake and end at the centre, all the slices will be of equal size **and** have an equal area of icing. This is very important. This is quite easy to prove for cakes in the shape of any regular polygon, using the fact that the area of a triangle is base*height/2.

I need you to write me a program or function to show me how to cut my cake.

The code will take 2 inputs: the number of edges on the cake (3 to 15) and the number of pieces to cut it into (3 to 40).

It will output a diagram showing the cake (a regular polygon) and the positions where the cuts are to be made (lines radiating out from the centre to equally spaced points on the perimeter.)

Some examples are shown below. Note for example that for the case `3,9` the slices are all equal size, but the angles at the centre of the cake are not.

You can orient the cake any way you like, but one of the cuts has to pass through a vertex for easy comparison of answers.

[image]

Scoring: this is code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Strata

[Strata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strata_(video_game)) is a puzzle game in which you lay coloured ribbons across a grid. When two ribbons intersect, the cell under the intersection takes on the colour of the uppermost ribbon. Here's an example puzzle, ready to solve:

After laying the first ribbon, no cells have been assigned a colour yet:

[image: Empty example puzzle]

Laying a perpendicular ribbon colours a cell in:

[image: Example puzzle with one ribbon]

Notice that, if the uppermost ribbon isn't the correct colour, the cell isn't filled in to let you know you've got it wrong. Also, if a cell doesn't have a target colour, it doesn't matter what colour ends up on top of it; the cell remains colourless when the second ribbon is laid across it:

[image: Example puzzle with four ribbons]

And a completed solution:

[image: Completed example puzzle]

## The Challenge

The object of this challenge is to write a program or function that will provide a step-by-step solution for a Strata puzzle. Here is the layout for the example puzzle provided above, rotated 45 degrees clockwise and with letters a-c substituted for the cell colours:

```
 ba
ab 
a c
```

For ease of the following discussion, I've labelled the columns 1-3 and the rows A-C.

```
  ABC
 +---
1| ba
2|ab 
3|a c
```

The notation for the output commands will be a single character representing the row or column to lay a ribbon upon, and then another character representing the ribbon type. For example, the command `Cb` represents laying a ribbon of type `b` on the rightmost column of this layout.

One of a number of valid solutions for this puzzle is `3a, Cc, 1a, 2a, Bb, Aa`. Another is `Ca, 3c, 2a, 1a, Aa, Bb`.

## Input

Input will consist of the layout for a Strata puzzle. The puzzle will always form a square, with side length  of 2-9 inclusive. Each character in the input will be one of the following:

- a lower case letter, representing the ribbon type which should be laid on top of the intersection in the completed puzzle
- a space, representing a cell where the type of the uppermost ribbon does not matter

Note that a puzzle can use between 2-26 (inclusive) ribbon types, and that the types will not necessarily a the first nth letters of the alphabet. Your program/function won't be provided these separately, and should be acquired from the puzzle layout if required.

Input may be provided in any reasonable form that is convenient for your chosen language. For example, you may accept input as single newline-delimited string, as an array or list of strings, etc. Please provide a description of how your submission will expect its input for testing purposes.

Similarly, input can be provided in any appropriate manner. For example, as command line arguments, function arguments, as a stream via STDIN, etc. You should only specify this if it is not immediately obvious.

## Output

Output should consist of a valid solution for the given puzzle. It should consist of an ordered series of instructions, each consisting of two characters:

- The first character should be a number or upper case letter; a number represents a row, starting with 1 for the uppermost row, a letter represents a column, starting with A for the leftmost column (e.g., in the puzzle above, the instruction `4a` would be invalid as there are only 3 rows)
- The second character should be the type of the ribbon to lay on the grid; this should be a lower case character, corresponding to one of the types provided on the input (e.g., in the example puzzle above, the instruction `Az` would be invalid as `z` is not one of the types used in the grid)

Your program/function can provide the output pairs in any reasonable form, and on any reasonable medium. For example, as a series of comma, space, or newline separated values on STDOUT, as an array for return from a function, written to a file with specified name, etc.

## Other Rules

- A puzzle is only considered complete when all rows and columns have had a single ribbon laid across them, and no row or column can have more than one ribbon laid on it. This means that your output will consist of `2 * (side length)` instructions.
- This is code golf, so the winner is the shortest solution in bytes. In the event of a tie, the earliest submission wins.

## Test Cases

```
Input:

 ba
ab 
a c

Possible output:
3a, Cc, 1a, 2a, Bb, Aa
```

---

**Sandbox comments:**

This is my first PPCG question, so I tried to make sure every angle was covered. I think I may have gone overboard though, do you think I should get rid of any sections?

As this isn't a puzzle of my own invention, would there be any problems with posting in-game screenshots?

This puzzle is actually pretty easy to work out if you employ a backtracking technique - find a row or column consisting of a single colour, ignoring spaces and cells which have been crossed once. Add this instruction pair to the end of the prototype solution, then mark all the cells as having been crossed once (or twice). Repeat this `2 * (side length)` times and you'll have a solution, if there is one to be found.

I want to discourage brute force solutions, so I'm going to come up with a 9x9 test case with more than 10 different types. My stats skills aren't up to much, but I think that, for a puzzle with side length `n` and number of ribbon types `t`, the total number of possible ways to lay ribbons on the grid is:

```
(2n)! * (2n)^t
```

Could anyone double check that for me? Also, if I were to put in a 9x9, 10-type test case, would that be big enough to rule out a brute force solution? Should I impose some form of computation time limit, and if so, how long on what sort of machine?

Comment: @trichoplax There is indeed a solution which is significantly faster than brute force, which is as described in my comments. For a puzzle of side length `n`, it requires exactly `2n` iterations to find a solution if one exists, and requires a maximum of `[the (2n)th triangle number]` row/column inspections in the worst case scenario. I can add a discussion of this to the main body of the challenge, but I'm worried that it's already too long!

Comment: I misread that part and thought that was the brute force solution - but I can see now that it is much faster - I'll delete my irrelevent comment...

Comment: I confirm your count for a really brute force solution. It's possible to optimise slightly by observing that if there's a sequence of parallel ribbons then the order in which they're placed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

### Just repeat yourself

Write a program that outputs "Do not repeat yourself!"

Your program code must respect the following constraints :

- its length must be an even number
- each character that is in position `2n` (where `n` is an integer > 0) must be equal to the character in position `2n-1`. The second character of the program is equal to the first, the fourth is equal to the third, etc.

**Examples:**

`HHeellllooWWoorrlldd` is a valid program

`123` or `AAABBB` or `HHeello` are incorrect

This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins!

Comment: This rules out most languages which require a keyword to output. For example, `print`, `put` or `output` would be excluded. Maybe there is some way of specifying the constraints to allow many languages to compete, while still being highly restrictive? I can't think of a way, but I wonder if it would help to say "meet 2 of 3 constraints" rather than "meet 2 constraints". Hopefully someone else can come up with a better way that I can't think of...

Comment: @trichoplax maybe "each character in the source code must have one and only one neighbour at the left, the right, the bottom or the top with the same character value".

Comment: @SuperChafouin Based on that, would comments be allowed?

Comment: @ASCII yes comments should not be allowed, that would be too easy (just double each line and add "\\")

Comment: I think I'll stay on my current rules - they sure rule out some languages, but a lot can still compete. These questions also exclude a lot of languages, yet they are popular and interesting imho : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52809/40-numbers-in-9-bytes http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39993/write-a-square-program-that-outputs-the-number-of-times-it-has-been-unrolled

Answer (score 1):

## Compute factorials [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In the style of the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/38891) catalog, this question is a collection of the shortest programs that compute a factorial (a common task for new programmers) in any given language.

### Specifications

Your program must take a positive integer as input from STDIN, and output the corresponding factorial to STDOUT (or your language's closest alternatives).
Your program must also accept the special case of `0! = 1` if 0 is entered. No negative numbers will be entered.

Your program must handle numbers up to 40 factorial (8.159152832×10⁴⁷). *Sandbox question: Is 40 factorial too large a minimum requirement? I was also considering 50 factorial is 40 is too small.*

### Test Cases

```
3
6

6
720

0
1

11
39916800
```

### Additional Rules

- This is not about finding the language with the shortest approach for computing factorials, this is about finding the shortest approach in every language. Because of this, no answer will be marked as accepted.
- Submissions are scored in bytes in an appropriate preexisting encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8. For example, Piet is scored in codels rather than bytes. If you're not sure how your language is scored, you can ask on Meta.
- Nothing can be printed to STDERR.
- Feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge. If anyone wants to abuse this by creating a language where the empty program computes factorials, then congrats, you've just created a boring answer.
- Your language must have a valid way to test your program (through an interpreter, compiler, etc.) If there aren't any, you can write one yourself.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed except where specified by these rules.

*leaderboard snippet will be added once this challenge is posted*

Comment: For languages with several integer types/ranges, how high do we need to support? There's a big difference between doing this with `int` and `BigInteger` in Java, for instance.

Comment: It's up to you, but I think it'd be more interesting to include `0! = 1` as valid input as well (i.e. input nonnegative integer rather than positive). Also, if [FizzBuzz](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5855/21487) is happening soon, it might be good to wait a while before doing another catalogue.

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks for that reminder, I overlooked the special `0! = 1` rule when writing this challenge. As for FizzBuzz, if it gets posted soon I'll make sure to leave this unposted for a little while.

Comment: @Geobits Thanks for pointing that out, didn't think there would be a problem. Programs must support numbers between 0 and 2^31 -1 inclusive.

Comment: Hmm. I meant more a limit on the *output* rather than input, since it grows so quickly. Trying to find the factorial of 2^31-1 would probably break *most* languages :)

Comment: @Geobits Yup, I tried 50 factorial and it was **really** big. I've changed it so programs must support numbers up to 100 factorial, but I'm not sure if this is too big.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I'd argue that, because the amount of observable atoms in Universe is about [10^80 atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_.E2.80.94_number_of_atoms), 50! is almost to big. It might be annoying to check results with slower languages.

Comment: Also, I'd leave out the requirement for valid interpreter - because, depending on language, there might be no such thing - I'd take C++ as an example - I'm almost sure that there can't be **valid** C++ interpreter, because it wouldn't be compatible with standard (I may be wrong though).

Comment: @MatthewRock Thanks for your suggestions. I've changed the limit to 40 factorial, and changed the interpreter rule to "some valid way to run".

Comment: I also think that allowing the competition to have a winner could be more appealing, but that's a side note.

Comment: @Geobits WA ([1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2147483647%21), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log256%2810%5E19107526488%29)) suggests that you would need about 7.93 gigabytes just to store the number as binary.

Comment: There's an [old challenge to find factorials](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/607/20260) with 100 answers. What does this add to that?

Answer (score 1):

**The shortest code for testing reliable password ( for Vault Password Rank 3 puzzle )**

***Introduction***

I started playing Empire of Code recently, and there was some challenge.
The player is supposed to write a code on a python or on javascript to detect if passed string is reliable password, that is, contains at least one lowercase Latin letter, one uppercase Latin letter and one digit and has at least 10 characters.

It was quite easy for me to fit in 130 characters limit for rank 3 using javascript, however, I spent a lot of time trying to fit in 100 characters limit for rank 3 using Python. Some guy said that he has managed to fit in 71 characters for Python. I was trying hard but still couldn't reduce the code less than 90 characters. Is it possible to use even less than 71 character?

**Challenge Vault Password [ the following description is mostly copied from https://empireofcode.com/ ]**

*We've installed a new vault to contain our valuable resources and treasures, but before we can put anything into it, we need a suitable password for our new vault. One that should be as safe as possible.*

The password will be considered strong enough if its length is greater than or equal to 10 characters, it contains at least one digit, as well as at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter. The password may only contain ASCII latin letters or digits, no punctuation symbols.

You are given a password. We need your code to verify if it meets the conditions for a secure password.

In this mission the main goal to make your code as short as possible. The shorter your code, the more points you earn. Your score for this mission is dynamic and directly related to the length of your code.

**Input**: A password as a string.

**Output**: A determination if the password safe or not as a boolean, or any data type that can be converted and processed as a boolean. When the results process, you will see the converted results.

**Example:**

golf('A1213pokl') === false

golf('bAse730onE') === true

golf('asasasasasasasaas') === false

golf('QWERTYqwerty') === false

golf('123456123456') === false

golf('QwErTy911poqqqq') === true

**Precondition:**

0 < "password| ≤ 64

password matches by regexp expression "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

**Scoring:**

Scoring in this mission is based on the number of characters used in your code (comment lines are not counted).

**Rank1:**

Any code length.

**Rank2:**

Your code should be shorter than 230 characters for Javascript code or shorter than 200 characters for Python code.

**Rank3:**

Your code should be shorter than 130 characters for Javascript code or shorter than 100 characters for Python code.

**How it is used:**

If you are worried about the security of your app or service, you can use this handy code to personally check your users' passwords for complexity. You can further use these skills to require that your users passwords meet or include even more conditions, punctuation or unicode.

Answer (score 1):

## Cookie Clicker

Cookie Clicker: Simple, stupid, and yet strangely addictive. In it you must click a cookie (hence the title). Once you have enough cookies, you can spend them on items that will produce cookies for you. Eventually you will be getting hundreds, then thousands, then millions of cookies per second.

There are a few different items that you can buy for cookies: **A clicker** (that clicks the cookies for you), **a grandma** (that bakes the cookies for you), **a farm** (that grows cookies for you), **a factory** (that mass produces cookies for you), **a mine** (that will mine and process veins of dough for you), **a shipment** (that ships cookies from other planets to you), **an alchemy lab** (that transforms gold into cookies), and others that we won't worry about.

Let's golf a simplified Cookie Clicker.

## Challenge

Write a full program. Your program should always display the number of cookies as a whole integer. Every second, your program should add the current cookies per second (defaulted to 0) to the cookie count.

- When the spacebar is pressed, it adds the base click amount (defaulted to 1) to your cookie count.
- When the key "1" is pressed, if there are 10 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 10 and adds 0.1 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "2" is pressed, if there are 100 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 100 and adds 0.5 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "3" is pressed, if there are 500 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 500 and adds 4 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "4" is pressed, if there are 3,000 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 3,000 and adds 10 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "5" is pressed, if there are 10,000 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 10,000 and adds 40 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "6" is pressed, if there are 40,000 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 40,000 and adds 100 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "7" is pressed, if there are 200,000 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 200,000 and adds 400 to the current cookies per second.
- When the key "0" is pressed, if there are 50 or more cookies in the cookie count, subtracts the cookie count by 50 and adds 1 to the base click amount.

There is no input, only output, being changed every second to update the cookie count. No other key should do anything, so you cannot press enter after every key and have it do something.

## Other information

- This is code golf so shortest program in bytes wins.

## Thoughts for sandbox

- There are many, many more features I could add to this challenge if it is too simple. I feel that challenge entries for this will already be long enough.
- I do not see many challenges that ask for constant input. Does this mean that this challenge is a bad idea?
- Have I crossed a line?

Comment: Requiring real-time user input is definitely rare. One big reason is that it's fairly hard to do and (probably) often requires a library. Many if not most esolangs won't be able to do it at all.

Comment: A lot of people will ask if they can require the player to press enter after typing each number, so you should be explicit that this is not allowed.

Comment: It's a real shame that non-blocking terminal reading isn't easier to work around, although it has been done a few times: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54344/ascii-game-of-pong), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/reimplementing-tetris), [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37333/create-a-hacker-typer-program-that-renders-its-own-source-code) it probably would be a bit of a barrier. I do like the sound of this though!

Comment: The list should show what is being bought here (instead you can skim down the introductory paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

## The Drunken Knight

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [markov-chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markov-chain)

**Inputs**

- `a`: Starting location of the knight, e.g. `A2`
- `b`: Target location of the knight, e.g. `B4`. The starting and target locations may be the same.
- `n`: An integer equal to or greater than 0.

**Output**

The probability that a knight starting at `a`, moving at random for `n` turns on an 8x8 board, ends at `b`.

**Notes**

- The knight has equal probability to move to any of the squares which it can access.
- There are no other pieces on the board that could block any squares from the knight.

Comment: Any time constraints?

Comment: @Sp3000 I haven't really thought about that yet. Do you think it would be more interesting if I tried to disallow brute force solutions via a time constraint?

Comment: From a simple test (assuming my implementation is right), caching seems to be all you need if you want to bypass a time constraint (brute force ~10 moves in a lot of secs, caching > 100 in less than a sec). So I guess it might be better off without a time constraint after all...

Comment: 1. Is the knight moving on an 8x8 board? 2. Please tag [tag:markov-chain]

Comment: Ah, another thought which occurs: valid output formats? The obvious three are floating point to a certain precision and accuracy; exact rational; and exact rational reduced to simplest form.

Answer (score 1):

This is a raw draft about an idea for a popularity contest. Any input would be appreciated.

## My watch, it has two buttons

I have this watch with two buttons and a display that can show six characters split into groups of two by colons like this

```
12:34:56
```

Each character is displayed by a 5x7 LCD-Matrix, so arbitrary ASCII-characters can be displayed.

I'd like to call the buttons "select" and "modify".

The problem is that the watch is dead. It needs a new operating system.

Since I'm not very trained at designing operating systems I want you to write an emulator for my watch. The emulator should be programmable using the following commands.

- big letters `A-Z` represent short presses of "select" the corresponding number of times.
- small letters `a-z` have the same meaning for the modify button.
- `<` represents keeping "select" pressed for half a second (or something like that).
- `>` represents the same for the modify button.
- numbers in the code mean to wait for that number of hundredth of seconds.

You're free to program any kind of functionality into my watch, but it should at least be usable as a watch showing the time and as a stopwatch showing minutes, seconds and hundredth of seconds.

One thing I know about my watch is that it can be programmed to receive data from my stdin and send data to my stdout. So once the operating system is installed I could send data and a program to the watch and print the results of the execution to my console.

Answer (score 1):

## Spot the differences

Little Timmy is waking you up on this Saturday morning once again to help him solve his puzzles. You love the little bugger, but those Spot the Differences games are starting to undermine your patience. Like always, you plan to delegate this tedious task to Robotic Dad™ so you can better spend your time... planning for your child education? Yeah, I think that was the plan.
Anyway, you tell Timmy not to worry, that you're going to help him soon enough, grab a beer and sit in front of your computer to help your child solve those puzzles, once and for all.

Your task is to write code that will take two similar pictures which differ in a few spots and somehow output the differences between them. The format of the output is free, however a 5 year-old child should be able to get it.

Here are examples of input :

[image: a glorious abstract realisation of mine, 1]
[image: a glorious abstract realisation of mine, 2]

[image: wikipedia's example, 1]
[image: wikipedia's example, 2]

Since there is no formally defined output, this is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).
Please also keep in mind that you'd like to spend a little time sipping your beer calmly in front of your computer. In this regard, built-in solution should be regarded less highly.

---

Meta :
I plan to post a community answer as an example output, linking to the http://franklinta.com/2014/11/30/image-diffing-using-css/ article which made me think of this challenge and using a snippet to illustrate it. Is it enough?

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. If I want to sip beer calmly, surely a built-in solution is the best?

Comment: It immediately occurs to me that the easiest way of doing this is to XOR the two images together. BTW What is the input format?

Comment: The technical side seems like it'd simply be subtracting or xor'ing the two arrays, then the popularity side is very open-ended (just [draw freehand circles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/freehand-red-circles) around them?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor the father described in this question seems to enjoy his time in front of his computer more than with his child. He still wants to improve his child's future but will use any excuse to do it in front of his computer. Disclaimer : I do not encourage bad parenting ;)

Comment: @NickT & steveverrill I do not know the first thing about image processing so my challenge may indeed be too way too easy. Do you know how I could avoid simple XOR answers?

Answer (score 1):

## Cops and Robbers: Text Transformations

> #### Cops' challenge
>
> The cops must write a fully deterministic program that reads input from STDIN and writes output to STDOUT as its only side effects. The mapping from strings to strings performed by this program will be called *f*.
>
> A cop's post consists of such a program's source code, along with its length and the name of the language the program is written in. The poster must also prepare a possible *crack* (see below), and release it when their post is *safe*. A cop's post is *safe* when it remains uncracked for exactly two weeks.
>
> A safe post where the original code is *n* bytes long is worth 1/*n*² points. The author with the highest point total wins. The tiebreaker is popularity (sum of votes of answers in the robbers' thread.)
>
> A single author may not use the same language twice in two different cop answers.
>
> #### Robbers' challenge
>
> To *crack* a cop's post, a robber must figure out which transformation *f* the program in the post is performing, and write a program *P* in the language used by the cop, so that both *P* and *f*(*P*) perform the transformation *f*.
>
> The length, method, or complexity of *P* are irrelevant; as long as is produces the same output as the cop's original code for any input you pass it, the solution is valid.
>
> Successfully cracking a cop's post is worth one point. The author with the highest point total wins. The tiebreaker is popularity (sum of votes of answers in the robbers' thread.)

---

This is a bit hard to conceptualize, so here's a very simple example.

If the cop's post is:

> ### Python 3, 20 bytes
>
> ```
> print(input()[::-2])
> ```

(i.e., reverse STDIN and remove every other character) The robber's answer might be:

```
print(input()[::-2])# ) ] 2 - : : [ ) ( t u p n i ( t n i r p
```

as passing this program as input to itself yields a new program that does the same thing:

```
print(input()[::-2])#]-:)tpitip
```

As another example, if a cop writes a C++ program that rotates lines on STDIN by 90 degrees, a valid solution is a C++ program that also rotates lines by 90 degrees, *and does the very same thing if you rotate it by 90 degrees*.

---

**The difficulty for cops** is to come up with transformations that are short to express, but difficult to code around (and, of course, they essentially have to crack their own post -- but at least they know *f* in advance.)

**The difficulty for robbers** is to decipher the cops' solutions to find out which transformation *f* they're performing, and then write any program *P* such that both *P* and *f(P)* perform *f*.

Comment: "A single author may not use the same language twice in two different cop answers." Not a fan of rules like that. Anyway, is there anything to prevent a cop from using a function like "Return the (n/2)nd character of the string." In that case it's pretty much impossible for f(P) to compute this function. Or should the mapping be surjective? Also do cops and robbers have to use the same language? Finally, how do we prove that a robber's implementation computes the exact same function as the cop's, especially if the cop's code is obfuscated and undocumented?

Comment: If it's impossible for `f(P)` to compute `f`, the original post is invalid anyway -- cops must be able to crack their own cop answers and release the solutions if they go uncracked. Also, yeah, they would use the same language.

Comment: @feersum pointed out a more serious problem in chat: cops can post something like `x = readline(); if (md5(x) == 'f0a92b8efc0...') print x`, which is nearly impossible for other people to solve.

Answer (score 1):

## Watermelon Contest

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

You and your buddies are contesting a lone piece of watermelon left in the middle of the table. You decide to make a program to contest for you.

### The Goal

You want to be the **last program standing**. Then you get the watermelon.

### The Process

Every iteration 1 program will be eliminated from the watermelon contest. This will be decided by a **vote among all the remaining programs**. This means that your program will have 1 and only 1 vote to spend on the elimination of another program. Whichever program ends up with the most votes is eliminated.

This continues until there are only 1 program left, the winner. This entire process is considered a "round".

After there is a winner, another round will be started with a new piece of watermelon. All programs will be re-entered. When `10,000` rounds have been completed, the program with the most "wins" will be considered the "grand champion". All the rounds combined is considered the "tournament".

### The Catch

Every program will have an **opportunity to send a message** to all the other programs. The message must be the same for every program. The message is a string, up to 500 bytes long.

You may have a file in which you may store any data you wish from previous rounds. This will persist over the entire tournament.

### The Program

**Write a program or function** that accepts the following input in any (convenient) form:

```
[program-name], [message], "The Slug", "hey! don't vote for me!", "Chucknorium II", "a2TEI5ds#" ...
```

and outputs the name of the program that you vote for:

```
Chucknorium II
```

### Notes

- In the likely event of a tie, one of the high scoring programs will be randomly eliminated
- Messages can be anything that doesn't mess with stuff it's not supposed to (e.g. don't mess with the controller or other people's programs). This is what makes the challenge interesting.
- **You may not hard-code program names into your program!** In other words, numbering the programs randomly at the beginning of the game should produce the same output. Names are just more fun.
- For observation purposes, your program will still be run even if it has been eliminated. It will not, however, have a chance to vote that round.

Comment: This seems to reward out-of-band collaboration (or posting multiple answers, which is effectively the same thing).

Comment: So the winner between the last two is basically *always* random (since I assume neither will vote themselves out)?

Comment: @Geobits correct. Over several thousand rounds this should even out.

Comment: I see. There's nothing about how many rounds will be played, so I was wondering about that. If you add this, you should make sure to distinguish turns/rounds or rounds/games, etc.

Comment: Also, do programs continue to be called once they're "out"? If I want to track who did well each round, for instance, I don't think I can (since I think I only get input up to when I get voted out).

Comment: Good point. Yes. You just won't be able to vote. I'll change that (and other things) when I get to a computer.

Comment: I don't need to hard-code program names: I just need to agree a signature algorithm whereby the combination of name and message means that either the program is a collaborator or they're piggybacking on our agreement.

Comment: I see... How about a statement that prevents engineering to specific programs? Would that prevent pre-determined collaboration?

Comment: Can you clarify the format of the input

Comment: I hate to be a party pooper, but I honestly don't see the point of this KOTH since it seems to be more politics than programming. Then again I didn't get the cake cutting one either and look at how that one turned out...

Answer (score 1):

## An Assortment of Sorting

[Sorting an array of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) in ascending order is one of the most fundamental tasks in programming. Indeed, there are many algorithms which exist to accomplish this. While it may not be the most interesting challenge, particularly for "usual" languages, it can be nontrivial in many languages. So let's sort some integers!

Rosetta code features lists by [sorting algorithm and language](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms) of idiomatic approaches to array sorting. However, "most idiomatic" often does not coincide with "shortest." In an effort to make Programming Puzzles and Code Golf the go-to site for code golf, this challenge seeks to compile a catalog of the shortest approach in every language, similar to ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/20469), [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime), and [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/20469).

#### Task

Write a **full program** that, when given an array of strictly positive integers, will print the ascending sorted version of the input array using **one particular algorithm** that is guaranteed to terminate.

The sorting algorithm used must be specified in the post. Note that [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) is not allowed as it is not guaranteed to terminate.

#### Input

To ensure that the focus of submissions is on the mechanics of the algorithm rather than parsing input, a variable (with a name of your choosing) must be hard-coded in the program. However, the hard-coded value must be easily exchangeable; it may appear in only a single place in the entire program. For scoring purposes, submit the program that corresponds to the one-element array **1**.

The elements of the array may be in their decimal representations, unary representations (using a character of your choice), as byte arrays (big or little endian), or as single bytes (if this is your languages largest data type).

All elements of the array can be assumed to be in the range 1 to 255, inclusive. Your program must be able to handle an array of any size from 1 to 255, inclusive.

#### Output

Output has to be written to STDOUT or closest alternative.

If possible, the output should consist solely of the sorted array with an optional trailing newline. The only exception to this rule is constant output of your language's interpreter that cannot be suppressed, such as a greeting, ANSI color codes or indentation.

The output array can be formatted in any reasonable way. For example, `[3,2,1]` and `3 2 1` would both be fine.

#### Additional Rules

- There should be only one language and algorithm combination per answer. Please submit separate algorithms in the same language or separate languages with the same algorithm as separate posts.
- All submissions are required to feature some kind of explanation of the code.
- Unless entirely unpreventable in your language, nothing should be output to STDERR.
- This is not about finding the language with the shortest approach for sorting, this is about finding the shortest approach in every language. Therefore, no answer will be marked as accepted.
- Submissions in most languages will be scored in *bytes* in an appropriate preexisting encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8.

  The language [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), for example, will be scored in codels, which is the natural choice for this language.

  Some languages, like [Folders](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Folders), are a bit tricky to score. If in doubt, please ask on [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/).
- Unlike our usual rules, feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge. If anyone wants to abuse this by creating a language where the empty program sorts an array, then congratulations for paving the way for a very boring answer.

  Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed (and even encouraged) to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language.
- If your language of choice is a trivial variant of another (potentially more popular) language which already has an answer (think BASIC or SQL dialects, Unix shells or trivial Brainfuck derivatives like Headsecks or Unary), consider adding a note to the existing answer that the same or a very similar solution is also the shortest in the other language.
- Built-in functions for sorting with a particular algorithm **are** allowed. This challenge is meant to catalog the shortest possible solution in each language, so if it's shorter to use a built-in in your language, go for it. However, you must provide a link that proves that the built-in uses whichever algorithm you claim.
- The input cannot be assumed to already be sorted.
- Unless they have been overruled earlier, all standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, including the [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061).

As a side note, please don't downvote boring (but valid) answers in languages where there is not much to golf; these are still useful to this question as it tries to compile a catalog as complete as possible. However, do primarily upvote answers in languages where the author actually had to put effort into golfing the code.

#### Catalog

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers as a list of the shortest solutions per language and algorithm, as well as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language, Algorithm, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size in bytes of your submission. If you improve your score, you can keep old scores in the headline by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, Bubble Sort, <s>101</s> <s>96</s> 90 bytes
```

If you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the last number in the header:

```
# Perl, Insertion Sort, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), Heapsort, 121 bytes
```

*Insert a super awesome snippet here*

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

---

### Meta questions:

- Should this be restricted to specific set of sorting algorithms or is it okay to allow any deterministic algorithm?
- Is the title okay? The catalog challenges tend to have straightforward, descriptive, searchable titles (with the notable exception of [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/20469)). I figured this title is clear enough while still being interesting, but perhaps it's better to opt for something more straightforward.
- At Peter's suggestion I've modified the input method. Arrays are now to be hard-code rather than being taken as input. This eliminates the need for parsing input. If I were to allow a variable to already exist, submissions would be snippets rather than full programs, which I don't want for this.
- Is the closed interval [1, 255] appropriate for bounds on the integer values in the array as well as the length of the array? Is it better to make the array an arbitrary size?

Comment: If you require people to label their answers with the algorithm name, I guarantee you will have at least one argument in comments about the difference between bubble sort, insertion sort, and selection sort.

Comment: Are extremely inefficient solutions like "Check every possible permutation of the list" allowed, if they are guaranteed to terminate? I don't mind them but they almost don't seem like sorting algorithms :p

Comment: @PeterTaylor Do you think it would be best to scrap the entire part about choosing a specific algorithm?

Comment: @Fatalize I don't see why not. I'm sure that's already a documented sorting algorithm, however inefficient.

Comment: To be honest, I think this question is on such thin ice with respect to dupe votes (e.g. 49935, 40744, 26947, 36447, 12028, 20478, ...) that I'm not sure it's worth dedicating effort to. But if you are going to post it, I would make two big changes: 1. Make it per-language, ask people to explain their code (giving algorithm name and complexity where possible), and allow them to give alternative algorithms in the same answer. 2. Ditch the I/O. The point of the "catalogue" questions is to showcase basic computational building blocks, not I/O.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is that per language, not per language/algorithm? And by ditching I/O do you mean allowing a variable to be defined containing the array (for example)?

Comment: Yes, and exactly.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Okay. I think I'm on board with the latter, especially since it's been difficult trying to come up with a truly convenient means of getting an array as input. Having it already defined scoots it a little closer to being a dupe of 49935 though. :/ But I think separating algorithms makes this more unique than the others.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I changed the I/O. Any better?

Comment: @PeterTaylor "and allow them to give alternative algorithms in the same answer." I think this is problematic because you'd still get multiple answers for each language, and if each language contains a few implementations they are spread out over the answers quite weirdly. That's why I suggested putting each algorithm in a separate answer and labelling it - then at least you know where to find each implementation (although I agree that the definitions of the different sorting algorithms aren't really applicable in some esolangs).

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I don't see the problem. Maybe because I see it as a catalogue of sorting, and you see it as a merger of many separate catalogues for bubble-sort, insertion-sort, quicksort, etc?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess I'm just generally not a fan of multiple solutions in a single answer (even for a normal code golf, I'd rather just post two answers if the approaches are significantly different).

Comment: @MartinBüttner, but if the question is presented as a catalogue of the shortest way to sort in every language then e.g. any answer in GolfScript other than `$` would deserve to be voted to about -5.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It doesn't need to be presented like that. All I'm saying is that separate approaches should be kept in separate answers. Whether the leaderboard reads the algorithm from the header or not is a different matter.

Comment: Regarding build-in functions: few language specifications clearly state which sorting algorithm has to be used, so all depends on the either the compiler/interpreter or the std library. The used algorithm may change over time, for example `C`s (g)libc used to use `quickersort` (hence the name `qsort`) but switched to a mixture of algorithms depending on input size - the name remained. Therefore a `C` answer using `qsort` should also name the library version to be verifiable ...

Comment: ... This problem carries on: an esolang compiler might be written in `C`. Maybe there's also an interpreter let's say in `Python` which ueses a completely different library, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## "The" Gaidhlig Challenge

The Gaidhlig language has some non-trivial rules when it comes to putting "the" in front of a word.

You're challenge is to create a program that takes two inputs, the first input is a string of text, a real word or made up that we can pretend is a noun. The second input is either the letter 'f' or the letter 'b' to denote whether the word is masculine or feminine.

The type of delimiter between these two inputs is your choice but must not be the letters a to z, a dash, or an apostrophe.

1. The first input is always assumed to be a noun.
2. The second input denotes whether the noun is masculine (f) or feminine (b).
3. We will always assume all inputs is valid.

You're output will be the the first input, modified for the following rules:

### Masculine Nouns (where 'f' is supplied.)

1. Before vowels: An t-
2. Before `b f m p`: Am
3. Before all other instances: An

### Feminine Nouns (where 'b' is supplied.)

1. Before `sl sr sn so se si su`: An t-
2. Before `b m p c g` : A' [with lentition]
3. Before `f`: An [with lentition]

Before all other instances: An

### Whether the word is masculine or feminine:

Words that start with `l n r sg sm sp st` always start with: An

### Lentition

When lentition is asked for, you must add the letter `h` after the first letter of your word in cases where the word starts with `b c d f g m p s t.` Otherwise the word remains unchanged. Further, you must not add an additional letter `h` if there is already a `h` in place.

**Examples**

Lentition of Aran: Aran

Lentition of Ghoul: Ghoul

Lentition of Goul: Ghoul

Lentition of House: House

## Examples

Cat f `An Cat`

Cat b `A' Chat`

fear f `Am fear`

fear b `A' fhear`

Obair f `An t-Obair`

Obair b `An Obair`

snow f `An snow`

snow b `An t-snow`

**Shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: I think you have a consistent typo: it should be *lenition*, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would love to hear your thoughts about the following challenge. Too difficult or contrived? Or should we actually [want more complicated and challenging](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7150/easy-challenges-and-hot-network-questions) tasks? I'll provide an example implementation in MATLAB by the time I post the challenge.

### Concert Harp: Pedal Meddle [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Sometimes I hear people say, ‘Why would anyone outside the ICT business learn how to program?’ Often, they get replies like ‘well, sometimes there are problems to which there is no software available’, but when asked about what kind of problems these would be, they’re forced to admit that all they really wanted was to make Conway’s Game Of Life for their own entertainment.

However, I recently found a problem that I think the home-and-garden programmer could face in reality. It considers a harp (a side effect sharing an apartment with a significant other) and a completely dumbfound pianist/programmer, who’s struggling enough with *one* pedal as it is. The harp in question has seven.

Now, for some background music/harp theory. You may skip as much as your musical background, or lack thereof, allows.

## Music theory (a very condensed version)

Both in a harp and a piano, the strings/keys are laid out as follows:

```
… C | D | E F | G | A | B C | D | E F | G A | B …
```

There are seven root notes, [A-G], with at some locations a | in between to signify that there’s a note in between. These `|`’s are address by making a note higher by appending a `#`, or lower by appending a `b`. For example, `C#==Db`, `F#==Gb` (and also, `Fb==E`). Using these notes, we can make a scale. The difference between D and D# is called a half note, and between D and E a whole note.

Scales are made as follows:
1: take the root note
1: Find the next notes by going up a whole or half number of notes in the following pattern (last step in `()` because that makes you end up at the root note again)

```
Major: 1 1 ½ 1 1 1 (½)
Minor: 1 ½ 1 1 1 1 (½)
```

For example, D major and A# minor
    D E F# G A B C# (D)
    A# B# C# D# E# F# G# A#

Of course, these notations are not unique, since for example `E#==F`.

## Problem

A harp has seven pedals, each responsible for one note. This note, they can either raise half a note, or lower half a note. For example, the C pedal can either make all C’s sound like C#(==Db) or like Cb(==B).  Let’s designate raising by a pedal setting of +1 and lowering by -1, and leaving it as-is as 0. Given an input scale, write a program or function that outputs how each of the pedals should be set to achieve all of the tones in that scale.

## Input

A scale designation. Scales are designated as follows: `R[m][k]`

- **R**: Root. [A-G]
- **[m]**: Optional: modification. Either flat `b` or sharp `#`
- **[k]**: Optional: minor key, designated as `m`.

Valid inputs would be for example

- `C` C major
- `Dm` D minor
- `Fbm` F flat minor

## Output

The pedal setting `-1`, `0` or `1` for each of the pedals, in the following order, reflecting the actual location of the pedals on a harp:

```
D C B | E F G A
```

Test cases: (not exhaustive; i.e., there may be more solutions, I only included a double solution to one input)

```
C , B#, Am -> 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0
Cm, B#m    -> 0 0 0 | -1 0 0 0
F#m, Gbm   -> 1 1 0 | 1 1 1 1
        or -> -1 -1 -1 | -1 0 -1 -1
```

Comment: I'm confused: you say "*Given an input scale*" and then describe the input as "*A chord designation*". Which is it?

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks, I was doubting between two versions of this challenge so that must've slipped through, edited now. What do you think of the challenge itself though?

Answer (score 1):

### Convert your Language to Turing Machine Code

You are locked into a room, with only a laptop and a single-bidirectionallyinfinite-tape, two symbols Turing Machine (Therefore supports only 0s and 1, and it has a tape which is infinite in both directions). Your perverted captor set you a task: he will set you free only if solve all of the problems on the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) page.

However, there is a catch. You are not allowed to solve the problem using your laptop, but you'll need to use the Turing Machine instead.

Since you think it will be incredibly tedious to convert your code to Turing Machine Code, you decided to write an source-to-source compiler on your computer, and since you're incredibly eager to get out, you decide to write your code in the shortest form possible.

---

### Summary

- Write in your language of choice an compiler that converts your language into your Turing Machine Code.
- Your language may not need to be completely transformed, but at least the basic operations needed for mathematical computations need to be implemented, therefore you will need to implement at least three of the following, with mandatorily being able to translate a looping construct of your language, then for each more operator implemented you will get a 10% bonus:

  - Addition
  - Subtraction
  - Division
  - Multiplication
  - Modulus
  - Looping (Mandatory)
  - Bitwise operators: &(AND) |(OR) ^(XOR) !(NOT) (they count as 3 distinct ones)

  In practice your code should be able to translate at least a primality testing algorithm into Turing Machine Code.
- When I refer to Turing Machine Code, I refer to code for [TML](https://github.com/WizardOfMenlo/TMLStdREPL) (Syntax explained later here)

---

### Technicalities

- The turing machine does not support decimal numbers, only binary, so you may (or may not if you have a better method) write numbers in unary. e.g `11111011` are respectively 5 and 2
- Since the Turing Machine does not have a predefined IO, you may consider leaving the return value on the tape and halting as returning a value. e.g `111110000` and halting will return 5.
- For the Input, you have full access to the starting tape, according that you don't do any other operation rather than initializing the variables. e.g if you implemented `add(a,b)` and run `add(5,7)` you may initialize the tape to this: `1111101111111` or `11111001111111` or `111110001111111` exc. but you may not initialize the tape to: `111111111111`
- [TML Language description](https://github.com/WizardOfMenlo/TML). TML which is the language your are interpreting your code to, uses a systems of cards, in this form `0{0-1}{0-1}{Integer}-1{0-1}{0-1}{Integer}` where the first value determines which piece of code to execute (reading a value from the tape and comparing it, if it is 0 it will execute the code after the 0 until the dash, else the other piece of code), the second one tells what to write on the tape(0, 1), the third one finally tells the tape whether to go left(1) or right(0). The last value tells us to which card to go next, with the card 0 reserved for halting.

Note that TML is not 100% complete, so if your code follows the specs, but doesn't actually work just let me know, so I can fix the Language interpreter (if it's actually broken)

This is Code Golf, so the shortest code wins!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler)

Comment: 1. The mention of interpreters is confusing: what you're asking for is a *source-to-source compiler*. 2. It would be useful to mention in the first sentence that the TM only supports two symbols. 3. What does "*when to execute the card*" mean? 4. In what circumstances could `n` be useful? It just seems to overcomplicate the explanation. 5. Is the tape infinite in both directions or just one? 6. What are "*the basic operations needed for mathematical computations*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've modified the question a bit, I think it should be clearer this way, the only thing I haven't changed is the use of `n`, which I think could be useful if one were to implement something like a "pass" card (just speculating). What do you think?

Comment: That's rather a long list of mathematical operations! Is the intention to handicap higher levels languages because they support more operations and so will have more cases to compile? Write nothing is equivalent to writing what you read; move nothing is "Enter an infinite loop" if you wrote the symbol you read, or "See the other side of this card" otherwise. So all `n`s can be eliminated trivially except the infinite loop case, which can be eliminated by adding two cards `x` and `y` with instructions `000y-100y` and `001x-101x` respectively.

Comment: @PeterTaylor. The long list of operations I've introduced as sample operations, that I think a standard programming language should have, however I am no Programming Language expert, and I'm quite ignorant (yet) of the variety that they present, especially regarding the operations. Regarding the "n", I think that your logic is more than valid, and I will also project this change to the language itself. Thank you a lot!
P.s
If you have some more effective ideas for the operations to implement, please be welcome!

Comment: There are a *lot* of astandard languages on this site! The obvious language to use to answer this challenge is BF, which doesn't have anything more than increment and decrement. (And even a language as mainstream as Java doesn't have an operator for exponentiation or integer square root).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've now added a system of bonuses, what do you think? Do you think the question is ready to be asked?

Comment: In addition to the issue of languages not having all of the operations on that list built-in, I find long lists of bonuses unappealing in general. I suggest that you scrap the list of operations, and instead require that the source language has to be able to translate all of its own functionality. This would create an interesting tradeoff between languages which are powerful, but have too many functions to implement, and ones that have the advantage of being minimal, but are difficult to program in. If you go with this, make sure to require the source language be Turing-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, no! There's been a fire at Claus HQ, and it's destroyed Santa's flight route! He has called on you to come up with a route that has him arriving at every home between the hours of 9PM Christmas Eve and 7AM Christmas Day. He'd also like to finish his deliveries in as little time as possible.

Input

Your program will take data for as many geographical areas as you or Santa chooses to enter. For every geographical area to be added, your program will accept:the name of the area, and the geographical coordinates of the area's center and the number of "nice" children who live in that geographical area.

Output In a .csv file your program will place:

1) Each geographical area's name, 1 per line, listed in order, with the area to be visited first placed first, and the area to be visited last placed last.

2) Next to the name, an ETA to the area in local time, and estimated time of departure, assuming Santa takes about 1/6100 seconds per child.

3) At the last line of the file, the total number of miles travelled, as determined by the sum of the great-circle distances - determined using the Vincenty formula, assuming an oblate spheroid Earth - from each stop to the next. Other than as stated above, I don't care what your file looks like. Rules

-You may not use any external library to perform any task except the following:

--Converting from one timezone to another.

-You may give your output file whatever name you choose.

-Estimated departure times must be no later than 7:01 AM.

Scoring For simplicity, scoring will be done using US states as areas. The population inputted will be the number of 14-and-under Christians residing in each state.

You get 1 point for every thousand miles travelled and an additional point for every hour of travel.

Comment: 1. "*Vincenty formula*" should be hyperlinked to a clear explanation, and geode parameters should be supplied. 2. Converting between timezones isn't hard, and doesn't need an external library, but the input does need to include the timezones. It would also be good to state explicitly whether or not the International Date Line needs to be taken into consideration. 3. We have no way of calculating travel times, because you haven't given us a speed. We also have no way of scoring our programs, because you haven't supplied the test data.

Answer (score 1):

## First 100 Twin Primes

#### What Are Twin Primes?

Twin primes are two prime numbers that has a gap of 2 between them; i.e. 3-5, 5-7, 11-13...

---

#### Goal

- Take no input and print first 100 twin primes to STDOUT.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

#### Rules

- Your submission should be an executable complete program.
- Every prime couple should be on a new line.
- Printed twins should have a space between them.
- All standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules are applied.

---

#### Restrictions

- No usage of built-in or external methods or functions that returns a
  prime number.
- No hardcoded prime numbers except 2 (as number, not count).

---

Any suggestions? I looked to similar questions but i couldn't see an identical one.

Comment: Unfortunately, we consider questions for which most solutions can be easily transferred duplicates, so without the restriction on builtins (and probably even with) your question would be closed as a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/find-the-nth-pair-of-twin-primes

Answer (score 1):

## Nondeterministic Turing Machine

### Introduction

We all know the concept of Turing machines, if not let's reiterate the concept. We have the following things that define a Turing machine:

- A *tape* that is divided into cells and is (potentially) infinite to the right.
- A *read/write* head that moves along the tape and reads and writes from it
- A *state* that changes according to what the head read
- A *transition function* that defines state changes and the direction in which the head shall move, based on the current state and the input read.

We can now have to supply some input, and the definition of the transition function (the set of states is implicit, and contains all states defined in the function). Additionally we assume that the alphabet is [0-9a-zA-Z!?()^+-] and *space* is the blank symbol. The tape head is then postioned over the leftmost character on the *tape*, which in our case is the first character of the input tape. The machine then starts applying the transition function. The computation continues until one of the following happens:

- The machine reaches the *HALT* state
- There is no transition defined in the transition function for the current state with the given input.

If the first case occurs, we say that the machine "accepts" the word. If the second case occurs we say that the machine "rejects" the word.

We can now extend this definition, to obtain a *nondeterministic* Turing Machine. To do this we allow the transition function to define more than one "next" state for each state/input combination. The machine can then choose which "execution path" to take. We then say that the machine accepts the word if it reaches the "HALT" state in *any* execution path, and it rejects it if it does not reach this state in *all* exection pats.

### Problem definition

You must supply a program or function that accepts a `string` and returns a `truth-ish value` (either true/false, or 0/1, or anything else, at long as the meaning is clear) indicating wheter the word is accepted for at least one computation path or not. The input has the following for:

```
(<current_state>,<input_read>,<output>,<follow_up_state>,<move_direction>)
```

All the parts of the tuple are provided as strings where

- `<input read>` is a string of length 1, which can contain any character except ","
- `<output>` is also a string of length 1
- `<move_direction>` is either "l" (move left) or "r" (move right)

You may assume the following:

- The machine will always halt (i.e. no infite loops)
- There is only one state on which the machine halts which is *HALT*
- The alphabet is [0-9a-zA-Z!?()^+-] plus *space* as the blank symbol
- The leftmost character is always a blank, to indicate the ending of the tape on the left side.
- States are defined implicitly by the tranistion function. So the only states the machine knows are the one that occure during the definition of the transition function and there is no explicit definition of the states.
- The initial state is always `s_i`

The input has the following form

```
<nr_of_tuples_for_definition_of_transition_function>
<tuple_1>
<tuple_2>
...
<tuple_n>
<input_string>
```

All lines end with a newline character (\n) and the input string is not under double quotes.

Standard loopholes are disallowed! Shortest answer in byte wins.

## Notes

Working example is still missing, I'll update that in the following days

Comment: "*The machine then starts the computation at the beginning of the input*": I suggest adding "*i.e. with the first character under the tape head, and the others to the right*". I'm not sure what you mean by "*States are defined implicitly by the tranistion function*".

Comment: Followup questions: 1. What characters can appear in the name of a state? 2. What delimiters occur between the tuples in the input? 3. What delimits the end of the initial tape contents and the start of the tuples?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I just realized that I didnt think the input part through, I'll need some time to rethink that.

Comment: I realised today that there's another thing which needs specifying in the input: what is the starting state? This could done implicitly by saying that it's the `<current_state>` of the first tuple.

Comment: I added input specification. Do you think this is an adequate method to provide the input?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 1):

## Rounding Fractions

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [rational-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers)

Back in the old days of game programming, before FPUs were the norm, games predominantly used fixed-point math to represent non-integer values. Typically, the lower 8 or 12 bits of a 32-bit word are used as fractional parts, and the rest are treated as the integral part. Sometimes when looking at fixed-point constants in old game code, I get confused trying to figure out what they were actually trying to approximate, particularly if it's not a number between 0 and 1 (0x4C = 0.3, 0x119 = 1.1?, 0x73 = ???).

Since just rounding 1/256ths and 1/4096ths has a limited range of applications, the challenge here is to take any integer ratio a/b, and output the simplest fraction that rounds down to it. More specifically, output the ratio p/q *with lowest denominator* such that a/b ≤ p/q < (a+1)/b.

This code should support any non-negative a and positive b up to at least 10,000, and should run in a reasonable time for anything in that range (nothing on the order of minutes, at least). Answers should be *correct*, i.e., no rounding errors due to floating-point. Answers can be in the form of a full program or function, and use any convenient input / output (a string '1/2', an ordered pair (1, 2), a list of two integers {1, 2}, etc).

This challenge is code-golf, lowest score in bytes wins.

Some test cases:

```
1/3 -> 1/3
4/10 -> 2/5
33/100 -> 1/3
66/100 -> 2/3
67/100 -> 19/28
115/256 -> 9/20  (who knew?)
0/417 -> 0/1
653/654 -> 653/654
1404/702 -> 2/1
```

### Sandbox Questions

Hey! I'm a long-time lurker, first-time-question-asker; I'm *pretty* sure this hasn't been asked before (more general than "Un-round fractions", not quite "Closest fraction"). Not sure what to set for a deadline before accepting an answer, since this is my first time actually participating. Anything else obvious I missed?

Comment: Don't set a deadline before accepting an answer, at least in the sense of putting a date in the question. As a rule of thumb, wait a week, accept the winning answer, and if someone later posts an improved answer then change the accepted answer.

Comment: [Sort of duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38104/8478)? The differences seem to be normal rounding vs rounding down and the odd restriction to a single loop in the existing challenge.

Comment: That challenge is only about decimals, whereas this starts with an arbitrary rational number. Not sure if that's enough of a differentiation, but this one's broader, I guess.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I agree it's borderline, but some of the answers to the older question couldn't easily be adapted because they rely on converting float to string, and that only works in base 10.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is a duplicate. floor(x)=round(x-0.5)

Comment: @ChristianIrwan, why is that relevant?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, sorry, misread.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Find runs of triple multiples of squares

Your task is simple: For a given input N, find all runs of three or more consecutive integers less than N which are all perfect squares or multiples of perfect squares (of numbers greater than 1, obviously).  You should then list each triplet (or greater) on a single line, indicating the square and the factor that divides it, e.g. `48 = 2² * 12`.  If a number is a product of two (or more) perfect squares, you may write it in either of two ways, e.g. `100 = 2² * 5²` or `100 = 10²`.  If your language doesn't support the `²` character, you may use `^2` instead.  For example, for an N of 1000, your code should produce the following:

```
48 = 2² * 12, 49 = 7², 50 = 5² * 2
98 = 7² * 2, 99 = 3² * 11, 100 = 10²
124 = 2² * 31, 125 = 5² * 5, 126 = 3² * 14
242 = 11² * 2, 243 = 9² * 3, 244 = 2² * 61, 245 = 7² * 5
342 = 3² * 38, 343 = 7² * 7, 344 = 2² * 86
350 = 5² * 14, 351 = 3² * 39, 352 = 4² * 22
423 = 3² * 47, 424 = 2² * 106, 425 = 5² * 17
475 = 5² * 19, 476 = 2² * 119, 477 = 3² * 53
548 = 2² * 137, 549 = 3² * 61, 550 = 5² * 22
603 = 3² * 67, 604 = 2² * 151, 605 = 11² * 5
724 = 2² * 181, 725 = 5² * 29, 726 = 11² * 6
774 = 3² * 86, 775 = 5² * 31, 776 = 2² * 194
844 = 2² * 211, 845 = 13² * 5, 846 = 3² * 94, 847 = 11² * 7, 848 = 4² * 53
```

or

```
48 = 2² * 12, 49 = 7², 50 = 5² * 2
98 = 7² * 2, 99 = 3² * 11, 100 = 2² * 5²
124 = 2² * 31, 125 = 5² * 5, 126 = 3² * 14
242 = 11² * 2, 243 = 3² * 3² * 3, 244 = 2² * 61, 245 = 7² * 5
342 = 3² * 38, 343 = 7² * 7, 344 = 2² * 86
350 = 5² * 14, 351 = 3² * 39, 352 = 2² * 2² * 22
423 = 3² * 47, 424 = 2² * 106, 425 = 5² * 17
475 = 5² * 19, 476 = 2² * 119, 477 = 3² * 53
548 = 2² * 137, 549 = 3² * 61, 550 = 5² * 22
603 = 3² * 67, 604 = 2² * 151, 605 = 11² * 5
724 = 2² * 181, 725 = 5² * 29, 726 = 11² * 6
774 = 3² * 86, 775 = 5² * 31, 776 = 2² * 194
844 = 2² * 211, 845 = 13² * 5, 846 = 3² * 94, 847 = 11² * 7, 848 = 2² * 2² * 53
```

The input may be supplied via command line, user input, read from a file, or any other means you see fit (though it should not be hardcoded).  This is code golf, so shortest code wins.  Usual loopholes apply.

Note that these numbers are sometimes called "non-squarefree" numbers, which are listed at [A013929](http://oeis.org/A013929).  (This lists all non-squarefree numbers, not just consecutive ones, so it may be useful as a reference, but is not a direct source.)

Side note: The 242-245 and 844-848 runs are the only sets of more than 3 below 1000.  It's possible that they become more common at higher numbers, but so far, graphing the sets I know about produces a pretty steady line, with no noticeable curve towards greater or reduced frequency.  It would be interesting to see a mathematical proof on whether there are or are not an infinite number of these sets...

Comment: 1. What is the relevance of `N`? It seems to be taken as input and then not used. 2. You're missing an important qualification. All integers are multiples of the perfect square 1². 3. This question would benefit from a link to [OEIS A013929](http://oeis.org/A013929)

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  It's just a cap so your program doesn't run forever.  Oh, and obviously 1² would be disqualified, I can make some clarifications.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: I already accounted for that.  Non-Unicode languages can use `^2`.  It's an extra byte, though, so might be more golf-friendly to use `²`.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Sorry, must have overlooked that. I suppose for interpreters which expect the source code to be UTF-8, it would be two bytes either way.

Comment: Re the side note, see comments on [A045882](http://oeis.org/A045882).

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Well alright then.  Looks like you have to get into some pretty high numbers to see longer runs.  Though it still doesn't answer the question as to whether they become more or less frequent the higher you go.  I was surprised, for example, to discover there were fewer triplets between 500-1000 than between 0-500.  This might be a bit off-topic for PPCG though.  Maybe should start a thread in Mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

## DND Level Tables

In 3rd edition DND, there a lot of stats that you have to keep track for when you level up. Let's fix that by making some nice tables for them.

### Crash Course on 3rd edition DND

3rd edition DND is very complex since it does not have "classes" in the traditional sense of most RPG games. Instead of picking a class when you create a character and more or less sticking to it, in 3rd edition you can actually "opt in" into any class you want at any time. Essentially, when you level up, you can choose to put that level in any class you want. This means that you can potentially have three levels in Rogue, two levels in Fighter, etc.

In addition to this, 3rd edition has special things called **skills**, which are unique to each class. When you level up you get some skill points that you can spend on skills. You can spend one skill point to get one "rank" in a skill. However, if that skill does not belong to your class you only get one-half of a "rank" in that skill. There are also **feats**, which are essentially general skills that don't belong to any class and have their own "skill points", and **stat increases**, which are little stat bonuses you get on level up.

All together, this is probably enough to make your head swim. Luckily, this challenge doesn't require you to get too much into the nitty gritty of this.

### Challenge

Given an number representing a level as input, print out a table starting from level 1 up to and including the specified level of the following stats:

- The total amount of XP you've gained to reach this level
- Maximum class skill rank you've gained
- Maximum cross-class skill rank you've gained
- Whether you've gained a feat or stat increase (they are not gained every level) and the number of it.

The stats should be in this exact order. The table should be formatted with columns for each stat, with at least 4 spaces between each column. The level, feat and status increase numbers should have their appropriate suffixes (like `3rd`). If you do not get a status increase or feat at a level, write `--` where the feat or status increase number would go.

Now, without further ado, the math for all of this. Assume x is the level.

Total XP:

[image]

Class Rank:

[image]

Cross-Class Rank:

[image]

Feats: If

[image]

(x divisible by 3), then you have gained your

[image]

feat. You also automatically gain a feat at 1st level.

Stat Increases: If

[image]

then you have gained your

[image]

stat increase. Unlike feats, you do not get one of these at 1st level.

### Examples

Sample input: `40`

Sample output:

```
1st    0    4    2.0    1st    --
2nd    1000    5    2.5    --    --
3rd    3000    6    3.0    2nd    --
4th    6000    7    3.5    --    1st
5th    10000    8    4.0    --    --
6th    15000    9    4.5    3rd    --
7th    21000    10    5.0    --    --
8th    28000    11    5.5    --    2nd
9th    36000    12    6.0    4th    --
10th    45000    13    6.5    --    --
11th    55000    14    7.0    --    --
12th    66000    15    7.5    5th    3rd
13th    78000    16    8.0    --    --
14th    91000    17    8.5    --    --
15th    105000    18    9.0    6th    --
16th    120000    19    9.5    --    4th
17th    136000    20    10.0    --    --
18th    153000    21    10.5    7th    --
19th    171000    22    11.0    --    --
20th    190000    23    11.5    --    5th
21st    210000    24    12.0    8th    --
22nd    231000    25    12.5    --    --
23rd    253000    26    13.0    --    --
24th    276000    27    13.5    9th    6th
25th    300000    28    14.0    --    --
26th    325000    29    14.5    --    --
27th    351000    30    15.0    10th    --
28th    378000    31    15.5    --    7th
29th    406000    32    16.0    --    --
30th    435000    33    16.5    11th    --
31st    465000    34    17.0    --    --
32nd    496000    35    17.5    --    8th
33rd    528000    36    18.0    12th    --
34th    561000    37    18.5    --    --
35th    595000    38    19.0    --    --
36th    630000    39    19.5    13th    9th
37th    666000    40    20.0    --    --
38th    703000    41    20.5    --    --
39th    741000    42    21.0    14th    --
40th    780000    43    21.5    --    10th
```

### Reference Implementation

Perl:

```
sub formatNum {
  $_=pop;
  $first = substr $_,-2,-1;
  if($first == "1" and length $_ > 1) { return $_."th"; }
  $digit = substr $_,-1;
  if($digit == "1") { return $_."st"; }
  if($digit == "2") { return $_."nd"; }
  if($digit == "3") { return $_."rd"; }
  else { return $_."th" };
}

sub space { 
  print " "x4; 
}

while(<>) {
  $limit = $_;
  for(my $c = 1; $c <= $limit; $c++) {
    print formatNum $c;
    space;
    print ($c*($c-1)*500);
    space;
    print ($c + 3);
    space;
    printf ("%.1f", ($c - 1)/2 + 2);
    space;
    if($c % 3 == 0) { print formatNum $c/3+1; }
    elsif($c == 1) { print "1st"; }
    else { print "--"; }
    space;
    if($c % 4 == 0) { print formatNum $c/4; }
    else { print "--"; }
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

[Try it online.](http://ideone.com/fork/KSK58b)

Comment: [Please use this and save imgur ;)](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: It's better to save the images from that with Stack's Imgur just in case that site changes and links break.

Answer (score 1):

### coreutils default behavior stdin/stdout

We have a lot of challenges to implement just one of these operations, but a lot more are missing. Instead of adding a challenge for each of them, I thought I'd see if I could make a multiple-holes challenge that's complex enough to inspire some code re-use. This challenge is to reproduce a small subset of what [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) does, namely to implement the default behavior of [almost] all of the GNU coreutils that (usually) read input from stdin or a file and send output to stdout or a file.

The utilities to reproduce are as follows:

1. `cat` copy stdin to stdout
2. `tac` copy stdin to stdout, reversing the order of the input lines (last line first)
3. `nl` copy stdin to stdout, adding a line number to the start of each line. Start at 1, use spaces to pad each number to a width of 6, and add two spaces between the line number and the original line
4. `od` I can't come up with a concise unambiguous way to describe the default output from od. I might skip it.
5. `base64` for every 3 bytes of stdin, split into groups of 6 bits, look those 6-bit values up in the base64 alphabet, and output 4 such bytes to stdout. wrap output lines at 76 characters. pad missing bits with 0s, and output an all-padding 0b000000 as "="

I'll finish filling out descriptions for some subset of the following if this idea proves popular enough to proceed with.

`fmt`, `pr`, `fold`, `head`, `tail`, `split`, `csplit`, `wc`, `sum`, `sort`, `shuf`, `uniq`, `ptx`, `tsort`, `cut`, `tr`, `expand`, `unexpand`, `yes`

The format of an entry would be either one program or one function, which can perform all of these tasks, just like busybox can. As a program, it might read its own process name to decide which tool to run. As a program or a function, the first parameter might be which tool to run. As a program, input should come from stdin and go to stdout. As a function, input should be a single string parameter, and return a single string.

Comment: I think it would be better to say "These ones have already been implemented" with links to the appropriate questions, and to then ask for a multi-tool which implements the non-dupes. That keeps things clear and, frankly, the ones which have already been done are probably mainly the less interesting ones.

Comment: @PeterTaylor fewer holes means less likelihood of code reuse. I'm annoyed at other challenges where code reuse is possible but it's not useful. I hope to see it in winning entries here.

Answer (score 1):

## Find the nested source codes

A cops and robbers challenge where the cops write between 2 and 8 programs that produce output in the same language and interweave the programs together. WLOG, let's discuss this action being performed on two programs. By interweaving, I mean adding the characters of the second program to the first program so that when the characters of either the (WLOG) first program are removed, the second program can be seen. Obviously, commenting in any program is not allowed.

The cops will post their combined codes, the number of different programs in what they post, and the language the codes are written in, and what the programs print as output. To get credit for cracking the submission, the robbers must post the split codes and what each one outputs.

As a general rule, cops cannot use a language more than once.

**Scoring**

A cop will receive points if their submission is safe for one week from the time of posting. Their score will be the sum of the two following.

- The first value is 256 divided by 2 to the power of the number of different programs used.
- Round the number of bytes in the combined codes up to the nearest power of 2 and call this number `x`. The second value is 1024 divided by `x`.

A cop will lose 10 points for every code that is cracked before the one-week period is up.

Robbers will receive a number of points equal to the sum of the following for each cracked submission.

- The first value is 2 to the power of the number of different programs used in the cop's answer.
- Round the number of bytes in the combined codes up to the nearest power of 2 and call this number `y`. The second value is 1024 divided by `y`.

**Example**

Python, 2 codes

`prpriintn("t"(hlellamlao")"[0])`

Prints `llama` and `h`

Codes: `print("llama")` and `print("hello"[0])`

Comment: Can I see an example?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Updated.

Comment: On interweaving: does one have to say which method they used to interweave?

Comment: Interweaving is done in order. The example given would be prPRiIntN("T**"(**HlElLamLaO")**"[0]**, where bold and capitalization represent the second code.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Think this is good enough to post officially?

Comment: I'd wait a day or two, and ask some other people in chat.

Answer (score 1):

### Sig-fig calculator

As a scientist, sig-figs are definitely one of the most important parts of measurements and calculatations (unless you are a theoretical scientist, where everything must be exact!). [Sig-figs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) is an important way of measuring uncertainty and accuracy of a value. To calculate the number of sig-figs for a value, use the following to help you (from [here](http://www.usca.edu/chemistry/genchem/sigfig.htm)):

1. ALL non-zero numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) are ALWAYS significant.
2. ALL zeroes between non-zero numbers are ALWAYS significant.
3. ALL zeroes which are SIMULTANEOUSLY to the right of the decimal point AND at the end of the number are ALWAYS significant.
4. ALL zeroes which are to the left of a written decimal point and are in a number >= 10 are ALWAYS significant.
5. Exact numbers in an equation have infinite sig-figs. For example, in the equation $A=pi*r^2$, $pi$ has infinite sig-figs and the exponent of 2 also has infinite sig-figs. (not included in the above link)

To calculate the number of sig-figs from a calculation, use the following rules:

1. For multiplication and division, the number of sig-figs for the result is equal to the number of sig-figs for the least accurate value (i.e. the value with the least number of sig-figs). For example, 2.000*5.00 = 10.0 and 4.5*6.00 = 27
2. For addition and subtraction, the result has as many decimal places as the one with the least decimal places. For example, 5.00-2 = 3 while 6.0-3.000 = 3.0
3. logs (including natural logs) have as many decimal places as the number of sig-figs of the value of whose log is being taken (I am not sure if this sentence of English is correct!). For example,  log(2.45) = 0.389.
4. Other functions, such as square roots, exponents, sines, cosines, etc. can be assumed to have the same number of sig-figs as its argument. So the sin(3.14) = 0.00159

**Challenge**

The challenge is to write a sig-fig calculator with the following functions:

1. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division
2. sine, cosine, tan, and their inverses
3. sinh, cosh, tanh, and their inverses
4. Exponents, including shortcuts for e^x and 10^x, along with sqrt. The exponents are assumed to be exact and has infinite sig-figs
5. log of base 10 and natural log.

The result of each calculation should give you the correct result, but insert a "\" before the last sig fig. If there is infinite sig figs, there should be no "\" at all. Also, undefined and infinite values should give an error or NaN or print "infinity" or "undefined". For example,

```
sin(3.14) = 0.0015\9265292
log(1.01) = 0.00\432137378
5.00*2 =\10
2.00^5=32.\0
```

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins!

Comment: The positioning of the backslash in the output spec is rather confusing, but I think that one of the examples disagree with the spec. `5.00 * 2` is `10` with one sig fig according to the rule for multiplication that you take the number of sig figs of the least accurate value. Of course, this runs into the problem that your (unconventional, I believe) rule 4 does not provide any way to represent the number 10 with only 1sf, but even so I think the correct output should be `\10`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks! It is now fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Complete the Digit Sequence

We have a string of digits with some elements missing and marked with `.`s.

```
74..7.1..1.3...8.781256
```

We want to fill the missing parts in a way that they would form an arithmetic sequence with the previous on next elements. E.g. `8...2` becomes `8642`. If this kind of filling is not possible with single digits, mark the positions with `?`. E.g. `7..3` would become `7??3`.

With this rules our original example becomes

```
745674111123???8?781256
```

You should write a program or function which receives a digit string as input and outputs or returns the filled sequence.

Input:

```
TODO
```

Output:

```
TODO
```

Examples:

```
TODO
```

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

*Sandbox note: this seems boring so ideas are welcomed.*

Comment: Idea: turn the entire string into an arithmetic sequence of as many integers as possible (after inserting spaces). e.g. `7....2` would become `765432`, i.e. `7 6 5 4 3 2`, but `7....3` would have to become `791113`, i.e. `7 9 11 13`, whereas `7....4` would have to become `727374` (`72 73 74`) or `767574` (`76 75 74`)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I like it although I would like to avoid the extensive brute-force approaches.

Comment: I just noticed there are a lot more possibilities for my last test case, like `72 53 44`. But yeah, I'm not sure how much one could optimise solutions for this. (Also, I'd still keep the possibility of given digits within the sequence, I just used the `x....y` format for simplicity.)

Answer (score 1):

## The Language Relay!

A typical relay race only has four competitors per team, but where's the fun in that? Instead, let's see how many teammates you can cram onto the bus to the stadium and still finish the race. (This analogy is starting to break down, so I'll cut to the chase.)

Your task is to write a program or function in **256 bytes or less**. It will take no input, and its output will be a program or function in another language. That program or function will also take no input, and its output will be a program or function in another language... and so on and so forth, until the last program, which will output the following:

```
.     \O/      .
|===== |_ =====|
|    _/  |     |
```

The winner is whoever manages to use the most languages. If there is a tie, the winner is the one with the shortest code in bytes.

You cannot use the same language twice, and different versions of the same language do not count as different languages. The output must also be different every time (no using languages that leave the program or function untouched.)

Here's a small example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){printf("print(\".     \\O/      .\\n|===== |_ =====|\\n|    _/  |     |\")");}
```

This C code produces this Python code:

```
print(".     \O/      .\n|===== |_ =====|\n|    _/  |     |")
```

And the Python produces the final output. I've used two languages, so my score is 2, and I'm going to lose terribly.

Comment: I'd implement some way to incorporate byte counts into the score because otherwise I'm sure there will be plenty of ties.

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might already exist, but through my search I couldn't find anything like it, so here it goes.

---

### Find My Number [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

My friends and I have made are playing a game where we have a variable `N` that represents a number from `0 to 10`. Using an expression they give us containing `+ - * /` for addition subtraction multiplication and division, `> < =` for greater than, less than, and equal to, and the integers `0-10`, we must find there number or what their number can possibly be.

I’m lazy, so I want you to write a **Program** that takes an input from STDIN or an acceptable alternative and return the possible numbers to STDOUT or an acceptable alternative.

Examples:

Input:

`N+3>N*2-2`

Output

`1, 2, 3, 4`

Input

`N+2=N*2`

Output

`2`

Input

`N*4/6=N*2`

Output

`0`

Because I might be caught, I want the program to be a small as possible in characters to avoid me friends seeing it, so the shortest solution wins!

Comment: What it is impossible such as `N<N` or the result is all real numbers such as `N=N`?

Comment: Well in the first one is impossible, so nothing works, so it doesn't output anything. The second one since anything works it prints all numbers 0-10

Comment: I assume that the `n` in one of the examples is a typo for `N`. This is not really an interesting question. The addition of `<` and `>` makes it marginally different to existing "evaluate this expression" questions, but it's still trivial to handle with `eval` in languages which use infix operators.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I think expression still works since I explained what I mean, but I will try to find a way to reword the question. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

## Gilbert-Shannon-Reeds Shuffle

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

#### Background

The [Gilbert-Shannon-Reeds (GSR) shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Shannon%E2%80%93Reeds_model) is a simple model of riffle shuffling close to how real humans shuffle a deck of cards. The well-known rule of thumb to riffle-shuffle a deck of 52 cards seven times for sufficient randomness is based on the GSR shuffle.

#### Algorithm

- Cut the deck at a position `k`, `0≤k≤n`. If there are `n` cards, the probability that any given `k` is chosen is `(n nCr k)/(2^n)`.
- Put the first `k` cards into one pile, and the other `n-k` in a second pile.
- Until all the cards are gone:

  - Where the sizes of the two piles are `x` and `y`, choose the first pile with probability `x/(x+y)` and the second pile with probability `y/(x+y)`.
  - Move the first card in that pile to the new array.

#### Challenge

Input: An array of positive integers, of length n<1000.

Output: The array shuffled once.

#### Rules

You may use any algorithm that gives equivalent results to the GSR shuffle.

Comment: Just to clarify: We have to shuffle *once*, yes?

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28454/194). This is one of the rare cases where I would actually favour closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking I want to make a KOTH challenge that has bots play the classic game of [Mafia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)). Bots will be placed in groups of seven, roles randomly assigned, and they play the game!

**Explanation of Game Mechanics**
The game proceeds in multiple turns, each turn consisting of Night followed by Day. At night, each person completes his role as will be described below. During the daytime, players (in real life) discuss the events of the night (communicated by God, a separate person who does not participate in the game besides prompting people to their roles.) Just before night, the players have the option of voting to lynch another player, the objective being to lynch a mafia member to help the town win. Choosing not to lynch is always an option if you think it is too risky to lynch someone who might be innocent.

In real life, God would tell everyone to sleep, then ask mafia to wake up and silently agree on who to kill, tell them to sleep, and continue with the other roles in a similar manner. Town wins if all the mafia are dead; mafia wins if they at least outnumber the town.

There are four roles in this game, but I have played many games with more than seven people with more ridiculous roles that are very fun to play. Each player bot is assigned an ID number indicating his role.

- Mafia - There will be 2 mafia in this game. The two mafia will come to a consensus on who to kill. If one is dead the other decides on his own. The two mafia can not choose one of them to be killed. Mafia has a role of either 1 or 2, which are identical in function.
- Inspector - There will be 1 in this game. At night he visits a person, and receives a report on that person's innocence. Both Mafia members will appear as guilty and the rest will appear as innocent. He can not inspect himself nor dead people. His number is 3.
- Doctor - There will be 1 in this game. At night he visits a person, and that person will not die that night. Doctor can not save himself nor dead people. His number is 4.
- Townsperson - Does nothing at night. Numbers 5, 6, 7.

**The Challenge**

You will write a Java player class who will have (at least) three important methods: `night`, `claim`, and `vote`. All of these three methods will return the player to 'act' on (of course, depending on your role), given an ArrayList of information that the other players have claimed in public.

I am not very clear on how to run a KOTH challenge and what github is supposed to do and how to use it so it would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction. As of now I'm still working out the exact details of a Java class to run the game, as well as making a generic Player class that the answers will have to extend and use methods from.

Right now, I have a generic Player class that each answer will extend, and each Player object has two Identity objects: a public, claimed Identity and a private Identity. The private Identity will hold the players actual role (kept secret, of course), as well as a doctor arraylist of Integers and a cop arraylist of Strings. If the player happens to be a cop, the controller program will add an entry to the private cop arraylist which will serve as his way of receiving a verdict. I'll make a method called verdict() which returns the last element to make the programming easier. An example string is "4G" which means that player 4 is guilty. This player 4 may be mafia 1; player numbers are just given for discussion purposes and to identify a player based on his claims and is independent on role.  Doctor is the same except integers because you only need to store who was saved that night.

The public, claimed Identity works in much the same way except that the controller will never modify it, only the player can. An identity object contains a role (an integer representing the role number), an ArrayList of strings called 'visits' (to be used if you are a cop or doctor, to store a list of people visited and any outcomes), and an ArrayList of suspicions to indicate that your bot suspects or is guessing that another player has a given role. It will also have a lynch value which can be changed during the day, and this is where a player decides on who to lynch (if at all). Finally, it will have a boolean for if the player is dead or alive. You had better not mess with this. The idea of having two is that you can claim whatever you want; so a Mafia can claim to be Cop or a townsperson and the doctor can claim to be a cop.

Initially your public claim ID is 0, indicating that you have not claimed. The program will give you your private ID, which will contain your actual role and and is not necessarily meant to be made public just yet. The program controller will only modify your private ID object, and only then if your are Doctor or Cop. It will append to the visits ArrayList in the private identity object the result of the visit; the doctor will have access to everyone he has visited, and the cop will have access to everyone he has inspected and their alignment.

The controller, each night, will ask Mafia 1 for his choice then Mafia 2 for his choice, then repeat, say, 25 times. If at any point the two mafia agree, then it stops because the Mafia have just made their choice. The number of times attempted thus far will be given to the Mafia's night method, so the code will look like `M1.night(<other players info>, 1)` then `M1.night(<other players info>, 2)`, etc.  is that arraylist of public identities previously mentioned. If no consensus, no kill. Similarly prompt cop and doctor once for their choice on who to visit.

In the day time, every player's lynch value will be 0, indicating that they do not vote yet; each player will be given 25 chances to act. An action can consist of adding to the list of suspected values, claiming a role, changing a role, changing the list of suspected values, voting to lynch someone, changing a lynch vote, etc., or more. Some actions are smarter than others, and your goal is to have a good action strategy. Upon each call of a players act() method, he will be given an arraylist of everyone else's public identity objects, as well as how many times before he has been prompted. This gives him access to what other players claim to be, who other players claim to have visited and outcomes, who they suspect as who, and who others are voting to lynch. If at any point there is a majority (more than half but not exactly half) of people wanting to lynch a person (No lynch, indicated by the value -1, counts too), then day time ends, that person is lynched and his role revealed. If majority voted -1 (no lynch) then nobody dies and day time ends.

Again, please guide me on how I should design my classes, controller, and what files I should put up and how people are going to test their bot at home. I would be glad to show you what I have so far, which includes a controller program and a dummy player class.

Comment: Note that we already have a Mafia KOTH [here in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1671/20469).

Comment: @AlexA. Note also that he allowed me to take over.

Comment: Some important notes:  The messages from the past post were a really good idea.  Use them.  Also, I think that its a good idea to have people submit a bot that plays a single role. Then, from round to round, simply switch in/out the bots for that role.

Comment: *I am not very clear on how to run a KOTH challenge and what github is supposed to do and how to use it so it would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction* I like this KoTH, and I've got quite a few of them under my belt.  If you [pop into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) I'd be happy to chat about it with you (and help with the code, if you'd like)

Comment: @FarazMasroor are you still planning on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a graphical representation of a Stern–Brocot tree of depth n

[image]

I am aware of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15934/find-a-fractions-position-in-the-stern-brocot-tree). Would this be considered as a dupe?

Answer (score 1):

## Play Chess with a One-Move Lookahead

> "I see only one move ahead, but it is always the correct one."
>
> – Jose R. Capablanca, World Chess Champion 1921-1927

This is a chess tournament with a twist: your chess engine is only allowed to look 1 move (2 ply) ahead.  In order to succeed, you must create the best board evaluation algorithm.

### Additional Rules

- En passant, castling, and under-promotion *will be allowed*.  Of course, it is up to you if you want to bother adding those capabilities to your AI.  I personally find these to be some of the best rules of chess.

I am considering making a "template" bot which implements alpha-beta pruning, and requiring users to just fill in the method for board evaluation.  Otherwise, there may be ways to stretch what it means to "look ahead."  The benefit for users would be that they don't have to write their own getLegalMoves() method.

Comment: How is the algorithm scored?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to specify "look ahead" which *isn't* vulnerable to stretching. Even if you just ask for the board evaluation.

Comment: Why would you need pruning for a bot that only looks 1 move ahead??

Answer (score 1):

## Broken FizzBuzz - Greg Is Confused [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

(FizzBuzz suggested by quartata in chat)

(Related: [Deletion of a blank line in source code which causes unexpected functionality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31647/8478), [What? No error?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/what-no-error), and [Write a line in program that looks useless](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19379/write-a-line-in-program-that-looks-useless))

Meet Greg. Greg is the new debugger at your company, and he deals with checking programs to see if they work. If they don't, he tries to find out why and fix them.

Greg is rather new to programming and understands the basics, but still gets tripped up by some advanced things. Sometimes, programs don't work and he doesn't know why.

You don't really like Greg, so you decide to play a game. You create two nearly-identical FizzBuzz-style programs - one which works, and one which doesn't.

For example:

```
n = input()
if (n % 3 == 0) {
 print "Fizz"
}
if (n % 5 == 0) {
 print "Buzz"
}
```

works, but

```
n = input()
if (n % 3 = 0) {
 print "Fizz"
}
if (n % 5 == 0) {
 print "Buzz"
}
```

doesn't. Greg is confused (but not by something as simple as this).

And because Greg has a desk only a few feet away from you, your code must be as small as possible, so he doesn't catch on.

### Rules

- Your correct program must accept an integer as input and return output as specified below, and your incorrect program must do something else (such as throwing an error or giving invalid output).

  - The valid program's output must print "Fizz" if the number is divisible by 3, "Buzz" if it divisible by 5, "FizzBuzz" if it divisible by both 3 and 5, and nothing if it isn't divisible by 3 or 5.
  - The invalid program's output may do anything else.
- Greg knows all programming languages to date, including super-obscure ones. Therefore, your answer may be in any language you choose (providing it was created before this challenge was posted.)
- You MUST have the two programs be nearly identical, except for one small change. The more concealed or insignificant-looking, the better.
- Greg uses PPCG and has participated in underhanded challenges before, so he knows about the C trigraph (`??/`). You can't trick him with it.
- Greg has also seen replacing ASCII characters with nearly-identical Unicode or abusing fonts, meaning that won't work either. Therefore, your program's change must work with all fonts, any may not exploit visual similarity between characters with different code-points.

  - Changing an `a` to an `A` is allowed, as long as it's not obvious that that's what broke the program. However, changing `a` to `<unicode character that looks exactly the same>` is forbidden.
- Both programs must be written in the same language with the same version.
- Your answer must include:

  - The language both programs are written in
  - Two programs: one FizzBuzz program, and another that is broken
  - How to run both of them (the commands must be identical with identical arguments)
  - Why one doesn't work (in spoilertext)
  - The output of the broken one
- Your programs must have a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of no more than 10 from one-another. (Meaning that you may add, delete, or change up to 10 characters in the broken code from the correct one.)
- Your score is the total bytecount of both of your programs.
- The winner is the post with the smallest score over 20 votes.

Meta Questions

- Is 10 too small a maximum Levenshtein distance? I was also considering 15.
- Are any of my rules already forbidden by the standard loopholes? I'd like to remove them if possible to make the post shorter.
- Similarly, should I remove or change any of my rules?
- This is a code-golf version of [this previous edit](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7733/12). Should I keep it as code-golf or change it back?

Comment: "*replacing ASCII characters with nearly-identical Unicode*" doesn't really express what that old chestnut does. "*Exploiting visual similarity between characters with different code-points*" is more accurate. Although it's arguable whether that covers e.g. switching space for non-breaking space, and I don't think it covers using non-whitespace non-printable characters (which with the right font are invisible).

Comment: I think there is something interesting here in making seemingly equivalent programs behave very differently. But I'm generally sceptical of [tag:underhanded] pop-cons, because they're usually way too broad and this one doesn't seem to be an exception. The primary cause is probably that there's no actual task that the program should accomplish. That means you can literally write *any* code that leads to failure from a small change (which is probably most code although the failure will not be surprising for most of those changes). I'd recommend giving a task for at least one of the two programs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe something like *"Your program's change must work with all fonts, any may not exploit visual similarity between characters with different code-points"*?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've changed it to two programs that should print "Hello, world!" (only the correct program will work). How does this look?

Comment: There are some very closely related underhanded challenges: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31647/8478 http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/what-no-error http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19379/write-a-line-in-program-that-looks-useless

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've added them in. Do you think they're close enough to be duplicates?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I can't predict how the community will vote, but I wouldn't mod hammer it.

Answer (score 1):

## Approximate an image using *all* colours

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

*I know that this is basically a subset of the then very popular [American Gothic in the palette of Mona Lisa: Rearrange the pixels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/american-gothic-in-the-palette-of-mona-lisa-rearrange-the-pixels/33206#33206) but I think it is worth making it a new challenge.*

*As @MartinBüttner pointed out, there has also been the [Images with all colors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22144/8478) challenge, but in my opinion it has very little in common with the proposed challenge.*

## Challenge

Given a image of 2^12 x 2^12 pixels as input, your program should recreate this image, but you have to use each of 8-bit RGB colour exactly *once*.

## Meta

These are roughyl 12MP images, quite large. So one could just restrict it to 7-bit RGB then the pictures would only have to be 2^18 pixels, that means e.g. 512 x 512 pixels which would be way more suitable for the challenges here.

Or does anyone know a convenient other colour representation?

Comment: [There's also this.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22144/8478) I'm really not sure you'll get any better approaches than those used for CH's palette challenge.

Comment: I was wondering that too on the other hand you have the advantage of exactly knowing the pallete and at the same time the disadvantage of having to use all the colours, even those that do not follow a "natural distribution" (a palette that is similar to "natural" images.)

Comment: I lean towards thinking this is too much of a duplicate of "in the palette of", but if it turns out to be accepted I'd recommend changing the title to "Approximate an image using all colours" to make it clear it's not "Images with all colors" again.

Comment: As noted in my answer to "in the palette of", it was directly adapted from a program which does this, so as far as I'm concerned it's a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

## Rearrangement Inequality: The Sequel [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

Read the previous version [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/rearrangement-inequality).

Your mathematics teacher looked at your test results on inequalities. Not good.

Hence he decided to give you some homework on inequalities.

Since this is about inequalities (how unfair), he decided to give each student a differing amount of homework. The exact amounts do not matter to him.

After allocating the homework, he had a bunch of complaints. Apparently, some students have some neighbouring students who have less homework than them.

Hence, he has decided to rearrange the students such that there will be fewer complaints. As long as each student sees that at most one adjacent student has less homework than them, they will not complain. (The students are quite reasonable.)

Note that he can swap the position of two students, but he cannot move a student into an empty spot as the empty spot has no chairs and the chairs in this classroom cannot be moved around due to safety concerns.

### Input

Here are different forms of input you can consider:

Optional: You can include integers in your input for the size of the classroom for convenience. This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), so input and output does not matter too much.

Function input: Container with [truthy and falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) values representing if a student is there or not. All truthy values must be the same, similarly, all falsy values must be the same.

Standard Input:
A grid of 2 different characters, which can be separated by spaces. Possible input:

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

or

```
_@@_@
@@@@@
@_@@@
@@@@@
```

### Output

The teacher wants to know how to arrange the students. Each student can be represented as an integer from 1 to n from the least amount of homework to the most amount of homework. For the input:

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

where 1 means there is a student and 0 means there isn't any students, a possible output is:

```
0  12 13 0  4
10 11 16 15 3
9  0  14 17 2
8  7  6  5  1
```

where the students labelled 16 and 17 are not satisfied.

Your score for every test case will be the number of students which are satisfied over the total number of students in that test case. It is guaranteed that there is at least one student in each test case. Your final score will the average of your scores over all test cases.

If you want to use another form of input and output, please clearly state it in your answers.

### The teacher has some concerns:

Please ensure that your code is deterministic, as the teacher may test it several times. You are allowed to code your own psuedorandom number generator if you need random numbers.

Please ensure that your code terminates within a minute for each test case, as the teacher is impatient.

The teacher has been to PPCG for a long time, so he knows all the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

The teacher has a very large classroom (100 by 100), and would be worried if your program fails to give an answer for such a large classroom.

### Finally:

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), and the winner will be the person with the largest score.

## Sandbox Meta:

I still need to generate some large test cases, so I'm leaving this in the Sandbox until I have large test cases. How should I show people large test cases?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a built in pseudorandom number generator provided it is always run with the same seed?

Comment: @trichoplax I may need to be able to test the code multiple times, so that may require all compilers/interpreters to implement the same pseudorandom number generator, which I am not sure if that is the case.

Comment: Ah, I see. That is definitely guaranteed for some languages, and definitely not for others... Banning all built in RNGs does at least seem fair to all languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Make a New Year countdown

***Editor's note**: This challenge is cancelled because it is the year 2016, and I'm too late*. XP *It is kept here for posterity*.

It is New Year coming soon. As such, it would be a great idea to make a New Year countdown. That is your challenge today!

**Happy New Year**!

#### The full rules

- Create a program taking from `STDIN` the current time and outputting a countdown until New Year into `STDOUT`.
- The program should be flexible - after Year 2015 has concluded, the program should count down until New Year 2017, and so on. See examples for more information.
- The program should count down until it is taken down by external means (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the Task Manager, the reset button, et cetera).
- The countdown may be formatted however you like.
- At the null second in the new year (YYYY-01-01 00:00:00), it should output 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes 0 seconds in your chosen format.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.
- The last rule: **Have fun**!

#### Examples

Given the input after `from:` the following countdown should be given, in any format you like (after `to:`).

```
from:
2015-12-31 06:00:00
to:
0 days 18:00:00

from:
2015-12-31 23:59:57
to:
0 days 00:00:03

from:
2016-01-01 00:00:00
to:
0 days 00:00:00

from:
2016-01-01 00:00:01
to:
364 days 23:59:59
```

Comment: Three things: 1. IMO this is close enough to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15660/194) that it's a borderline dupe. 2. 2016 is a leap year, so from `2016-01-01 00:00:01` to `2017-01-01 00:00:00` is `365 days 23:59:59` (assuming no leap seconds are added, but that can't be predicted in advance). 3. Because of points such as the previous one, for testing [tag:date] questions it's usually better to take the current time on stdin rather than read it from the clock.

Comment: For 3; changed the rules to get the time from `STDIN`

Answer (score 1):

## Clean numbers

We call a positive integer a clean number if it is expressible by using only a positive digit once or more and no other sign. For example 88 is expressible with 2's as 2<sup>2</sup>22.

A more complex example is

$$141289730531295606313143345858933 = 3^{33}3^{3^3}3333$$

### Details

The possible operations are

- exponentiation
- multiplication (only if the first part contains exponentiation as otherwise it is just digit concatenation)
- digit concatenation

Precedence is as normal. Power towers are computed from right to left (top to bottom).

### Task

***sandbox note***: which one should it be? I'm thinking d) now

- a) given a number return if it is clean
- b) given a number return the digit with which it is clean
- c) given a number and a digit return if the number is clean with that digit
- d) given a number and a digit return digit-clean numbers up to the given number
- e) given a number find the smallest digit or digit-sequence which makes it clean (eg. 63504 = 252<sup>2</sup>)

### Test cases

```
TODO
(11^1)*11
2^(2^2*22)
```

Your program should **solve every test case in a couple of minutes**.

This is code golf.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site doesn't have latex support. It should though.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I know and I will add image for the final version. I'm just lazy to do it already.

Comment: Unfortunately, Meta *does* have LaTeX support. You just have to double up on the dollar signs.

Comment: Not anymore... i guess

Comment: If combinations are allowed, then 2016=C(2^C(2^2,2),2) ;)

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 seeing that in the chat gave the idea for the challenge

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just suggesting combinations (which probably wouldn't be accepted anyways)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a challenge like this before, but it wouldn't surprise me if it already exists.

---

A strand of DNA is made up of bases notated by the letters `A`, `T`, `C`, and `G`. `A` always pairs with `T`, `C` always pairs with `G`, and vice versa.

Therefore, you can find the opposite side of a DNA strand by swapping all occurrences of a base with its complement.

Here's the catch: your program cannot contain the characters `A`, `T`, `C`, or `G` at all – in string literals or in the body of the program.

---

The input is a string of continuous uppercase characters (you can assume that this string only contains the above bases). The input can be any length. The output should be the complementary strand of DNA.

**Examples**

```
Input:   AC
Output:  TG

Input:   ACCTAGTAT
Output:  TGGATCATA

Input:   GCATC
Output:  CGTAG

Input:   TCTGAAACTAGGGGC
Output:  AGACTTTGATCCCCG
```

---

This is code golf, so the shortest program wins.

Comment: I think [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42184/194) is the closest existing question. Note that it's a more complicated question, and the winner is still only 24 bytes. I have a 16 char solution to this question in CJam.

Comment: It seems like this is basic character table translation in languages that support that, in [pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Xz%22GATC&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=AC%0AACCTAGTAT%0AGCATC%0ATCTGAAACTAGGGGC&debug=0) and [cjam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%22GATC%22_W%25er&input=TCTGAAACTAGGGGC) these answers seem near optimal, they're also kind of boring, idk if people will think it's too boring...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that's why I added the requirement the character restriction. I don't think it will be as easy to do a character replacement without using the actual characters.

Comment: @erdekhayser in many languages you can just use [base encoding](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Xz.%22AT%EB%B3%BE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=AC%0AACCTAGTAT%0AGCATC%0ATCTGAAACTAGGGGC&debug=0) of some kind to avoid that.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman simple thing would be to prohibit the use of base encoding...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I have a 17 byte Pyth answer using only simple ASCII characters. It is possible to solve this challenge without base encoding

Comment: @TanMath without base encoding I think most languages would just [add to character codes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XzsmChCd%22F%40SB&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=AC%0AACCTAGTAT%0AGCATC%0ATCTGAAACTAGGGGC&debug=0)...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think that is the only route to go, which is what I used. Any problem with that?

Comment: @TanMath not necessarily, but a challenge where the only challenge is working around an obvious solution by restricting workarounds isn't one I would personally find interesting.

Comment: @TanMath or just specify ranges around the desired characters in the `translate` command. Like this 15 char Retina solution `T\`B-H@-U\`H-BU-@`

Comment: 20 bytes in Seriously using only arithmetic on character codes (no base encoding or translate): ``,O`6╙(-7P/≈u6╙+c`Mεj``

Comment: Should I add a restriction on base encoding, or should I not post this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

## Format a list of words

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your challenge is to format a list of words across multiple lines that are no longer than a given number of characters, so that each line contains as many words as possible and no words are unnecessarily cut off.

### Input

The input will be a space-separated list of words and then a number that is at least 4.

### Output

The output should be the input words grouped into lines so that none of the lines contains more characters than the input number. The lines should be output in the order they were input. The words should be comma-separated, and each line except the last should end with a comma. If a word is too long to fit on a line, it should be cut off as little as possible while following the other rules, and "..." should be added to the end.

### Test cases

```
Input:
foo bar baz qux 12

Output:
foo, bar,
baz, qux


Input:
foo bar baz qux 5

Output:
foo,
bar,
baz,
qux


Input:
strength dexterity constitution intelligence wisdom charisma 10

Output:
strength,
dexterity,
consti...,
intell...,
wisdom,
charisma


Input:
quas wex exort 4
...,
wex,
e...
```

### Sandbox questions

- Has this been done before?

Answer (score 1):

## Smallest Turing Complete Interpreter

### Sandbox Notes

- Has anything like this ever been done before?
- Do you think this will be well received?
- In my research I couldn't find a simple definition of what makes a language "Turing complete". What alterations or additions should I make to the language rules? I would prefer that the language in every answer was not exactly the same, but at the same time I want to keep the complexity as low as possible (while still being Turing complete) so that *ideally* one of the answers would become the world's smallest (non-`eval`) interpreter.
- Are there any other loopholes I missed?

Let me know in the comments!

---

Your challenge is to make the smallest possible interpreter for a programming language.

### What is the language we are interpreting?

You get to create the language! You can implement any instructions you like, however the language must be [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). For the purposes of this challenge, your "Turing complete" language must be able to:

- **Store and retrieve an arbitrary amount of data in memory** The amount must be theoretically infinite, but your interpreter only needs to handle a minimum of 64 kilobytes (`256 ^ 0xffff` distinct values). The format could be an array of numbers, a string, a *very* large integer (if the language of your interpreter supports 524288-bit integers :P ) or any other format that provides the same number of distinct values.
- **Loop conditionally** The loop must also be able to alter the execution flow (if you implement a `while` loop that can only have one instruction in the body, it won't be able to affect anything outside of the while loop). This can be one command (eg: `while A do { B C D }`) or two (eg: `if A then B` and `goto C`) or any number that produces the same effect.
- **Print any ASCII character** This includes code points `32` to `126` inclusive. Newline is not required but being able to print characters outside of this range is fine.

It does not need to take input. Any extra features are fine as long as it meets these requirements. The language does not have to be pleasant to use, but each of these requirements must be usable in the real world.

See the languages [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit) for some inspiration...

### Input

- Your interpreter must take a single string containing the source code of a program in your language.
- The input will always be a valid program. You do not need to handle endless loops, impossible instructions, etc.

### Output

- A single string containing the output of the program.
- A single trailing newline is allowed, any other leading or trailing whitespace is not.

### Rules

- The only rule is that you **cannot use eval** (or equivalent) in your interpreter.
- Your interpreter must be a full program, not just a function. Input and output must be from `STDIN`, `STDOUT` or their equivalents.
- The interpreter and the specifications of your language must be posted in your answer. Make sure you include all details that prove the language is Turing complete!
- Your language can be identical to an existing language or a language from another answer.

### Remember...

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score is the number of bytes in the source code of your interpreter, so design your language to minimise this score.

Good luck!

---

#### Sample Answer

## JavaScript (ES6), 148 bytes

```js
s=prompt();o="";m=[];for(p=i=0;c=s[i];i++)v=m[p],+c?c-1?c-2?c-3?c-4?o+=String.fromCharCode(v):p++:p--:m[p]=~~v+1:m[p]=~~v-1:m[p]?i=m[p+1]:0;alert(o)
```

### Language Specification

Memory is stored on an infinite tape. The `pointer` variable points to a position within this tape. The `index` variable holds the index of the current instruction in the source code being executed. Each instruction is a single-digit number. The numbers do the following:

- `5` = print character ASCII code at `pointer`
- `4` = increment `pointer`
- `3` = decrement `pointer`
- `2` = increment value at `pointer`
- `1` = decrement value at `pointer`
- `0` = if the value at `pointer` is non-zero, set `index` to the value at `pointer + 1`

### Explanation

Using numbers instead of letters for the instructions means I can check with `c-3` instead of `c=="x"`.

```js
s=prompt();
o="";
m=[];
for(p=i=0;c=s[i];i++)
  v=m[p],
  +c?
    c-1?
      c-2?
        c-3?
          c-4?
            o+=String.fromCharCode(v)
          :p++
        :p--
      :m[p]=~~v+1
    :m[p]=~~v-1
  :m[p]?i=m[p+1]:0;
alert(o)
```

### Test

```js
prompt = () => input.value;
alert = (output) => result.textContent = output;
var solution = _=>{ s=prompt();o="";m=[];for(p=i=0;c=s[i];i++)v=m[p],+c?c-1?c-2?c-3?c-4?o+=String.fromCharCode(v):p++:p--:m[p]=~~v+1:m[p]=~~v-1:m[p]?i=m[p+1]:0;alert(o) };
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="70">222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222522222222222222222222222222222522222225522254222222222222222222222222222222222222222222225111111111111531111111111111111111111115222222222222222222222222522251111115111111115425</textarea><br />
<button onclick="solution()">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

Comment: You ought to add that all submissions include a proof of TC-ness

Comment: @quintopia Yes. I've been contemplating what the simplest way to prove turing-completeness is. At the moment the only way to check is by looking at their language specs and comparing them to the checklist in my question, but maybe there's a simple program that uses all these rules that I could require (or at least recommend) to be made and run in their language which proves Turing completeness...

Comment: The only way to prove TC-ness that I know is to reduce a universal language to it. But you can let the submitter decide which language they want to reduce to it.

Comment: 1. I would vote to close this as too broad. It essentially duplicates half of the [tag:interpreter] tag. See in particular http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40300/194 . 2. What makes a language TC is the ability to emulate a universal TM. This is often proven by proving ability to emulate another known-TC system and applying transitivity. 3. In "*a minimum of 64 kilobytes (`256 ^ 0xffff` distinct values)*", what is `^` and how does `256 ^ 0xffff` relate to 64 kB? 4. Not all TC systems have an explicit concept of loop.

Comment: 5. Output in ASCII seems to directly contradict your stated intention to "*keep the complexity as low as possible*" and inspire "*the world's smallest (non-`eval`) interpreter*". 6. The restriction against `eval` seriously constrains some languages' ability to process input.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, the broadness of the challenge is my main concern. I'm not sure there is a way to fix this without changing the purpose of the challenge as well. Addressing your other points: 3. There are `256 to-the-power-of 0xffff` different ways you can arrange the bits of a 64 kilobyte block of bits. I just worded it like this to illustrate that the memory can be stored in any way that produces the same effect (rather than enforcing a 16384 length array of 32-bit integers, etc). The wording could be improved.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 4. I assumed that would be necessary. How would it compute a recursive algorithm without the execution jumping back to the start of the algorithm repeatedly? 5. True. It's purpose was to unify the output of the languages and simplify testing but it would probably be more work for some interpreter languages. 6. That was to prevent trivial answers like `eval(input)`. I could make an exception for using `eval` to parse the input as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

## "Compress" text into Zalgo

Zalgo, the Nezperdian hivemind of chaos, is a type of text that [uses combining characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20310289/1122232) to make very tall and noisy text.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, maybe this will jog your memory:

```
<zalgo>




H̡̢̢̡̡̧̢̡͎̟͚̮͓͇̦̮̙̗̜̱̱͔̲̹̣̱̠̀̀͐̑̾̓̃́̃̍̀͆̇͆̽̔̒̚̕͘̚͜͝͠͠ͅE̢̧͓̺͉̟͙͇̳̰͉͖̺̻͕̰̱̝̳̙̰̟̠̯̘̰̲̎̑͋͂͑́͛̎͋̇̍̾̊̈́̂̽̿͆͛͑̽̒̊́͠͝͠͝͝ͅ ̨̢̟̳̥̖̺̼͎̩̘̰̣̼͇̰̫̞̜̲̰͔̗̠͔̩̻̳͇̾͌̆̑̍̄̊͗̓̃̆̊̄̽̐̂͛̏͑̒̓̆͝͝͝Ç̛̬̩͙̱̥̦̪̮̖͚͚͔̼̱̺̳̳̬̭͍̣͍̙̹̜̫̟̳͌̓͗͊̐̈̄́̏̀͂̎̃̈́̈́̎͋̀̒̊̀̈́͒̽͘̕͝Ȏ̡̡̨̡̝̬̠͚̠̯͖̹̟͓̮̻̲͙̖̪̯͇̍̅̂̌̌̒͗̈́̉͆̇̑͒̉̂̾̃̌̽͛͘͝͝ͅM̡̢̢̘͉̤͍̫̺̻͕̱̤̤̞̟̞̹͉͓̥̳͖̹̤̆̋̓͂̂͑̃̌͛͂̋̂̓̏́̀̾̋̈́̅̐̅̎̇̐̽͜͝Ȩ̨̛̭̥̹̳̫͎͖͈̳̠͍͙͉̻̼͍̞̜̺̝̻̝̗̳̏̈̓͋̐́̋͆͋̓̿͐͆̾̾̃͌͌̾̊́̚͘͘͜S̡̢̡̡̛̯̪̬̹̲̙̮̲̲̤͖͖̞̲̞̼̪͓͇̤̼͇͆͋̊̈̑̆̿̐̎͑̾̅̀̒̓̎̐̍̽̈́̋̽̓̔̍͜͝





</zalgo>
```

As a new twist on the age-old Zalgo generation problem, your goal is to take a string and "compress" it into a single Zalgo character.  You will write two programs, one which takes in a string of printable ASCII and outputs a single Zalgo character, and a second which takes in a single Zalgo character and outputs the original ASCII string.

Comment: I think the most golfable solution will be to encode the input in unary and use a single combining mark. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe require the zalgo output to be shorter in some sense?

Answer (score 1):

## Let's play Ticket to Ride!

(Note, this challenge was inspired by the board game [Ticket to Ride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_to_Ride_(board_game)), but is massively simplified to a graph-searching problem).

For this challenge, you have a list of cities (nodes), connections (edges), and tickets (`[City, City, Point]` tuple).  You also have a limited number of trains, where each connection takes exactly 1 train to fill.  For each ticket you complete (there is a filled-in path between the two cities), you get the ticket's point value.

Your goal is to maximize the number of points you get.  For example,  given the following graph:

```
A-B-C-D
```

and two tickets `[(A,B)=>1, (B,D)=>2]`, and 2 trains, then you should output `(B,C), (C,D)` as that gives you a total of 2 points, because you have created a path from `B` to `D`, which matches the second ticket.

Everybody will be working on the same large graph and set of tickets, so your score is the score of your solution.  **Your solution is a list of filled connections (not the code that generated them, although your code should be included).**

Comment: This is very unclear. "tickets (point value to make a path between two cities)" sounds like you need to have that many points in order to create an edge, then you say "Your goal is to maximize the number of points you get"... but you don't describe how you get points. And then "you should output `(B,C), (C,D)` as that gives you a total of 2 points": how does `(B,C), (C,D)` give you points?

Comment: @msh210 is that better?

Comment: 1. To check I've understood: there's a sense in which what we have isn't a list of edges but a list of potential edges, and we have to choose `n` edges from those listed to create an actual graph on which reachability analysis will be performed? 2. Is there any reason to think that the answers won't all be optimal?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. correct.  I'll make that clearer.  2. I believe that the optimal solution requires a massive big O, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, yep!

Comment: At the moment there's no runtime restriction preventing people from using an algorithm which considers every `n`-element subset of the edges.

Comment: @PeterTaylor When I post the challenge, I'm going to be including a single, large test case.   A submission will simply be a list of connections, not the program that generated them (although the program would certainly be nice)

Comment: If answers don't have to include code ([or at *least* pseudo-code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4687/194)), the question is off-topic on this site.

Comment: What about this challenge: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52496/uniquely-separated-pixels

Answer (score 1):

## Risk dice battle

Risk is a board game in which you attempt to conquer the world by attacking your opponents' countries. As the game progresses the number of armies involved in attack gets higher and higher, which can lead to a lot of dice rolling. I want you to make this easier for me. It's possible that my favourite answer will actually get used when playing Risk.

**Rules of Risk battles**

Each country in Risk must have at least one army on it. Therefore a battle can only take place if the attacker has more than one army (in case he loses.) The defender obviously has at least one army.

The attacker rolls 3 dice (only 2 if he has only 2 armies) while the defender rolls 2 dice (only 1 if he has only 1 army.) Once the dice are rolled, the highest dice of each player are compared, then the next highest. (If one player rolled more dice than the other, his lowest dice are discarded.)

For each dice comparison, the player with the lower score loses an army. If the dice are the same, the defender wins and the attacker loses an army. Note that this does not necessarily put the attacker at the disadvantage, as he frequently has more dice to roll than the defender.

Example:

```
               Attacker 6 3 2
               Defender 5 4
                        ^ ^
                        | |
 Defender loses 1 army -+ +-Attacker loses 1 army
```

For interest the probabilities are as follows:

```
                        Defender rolls 2 dice       Defender rolls 1 die
                        --------------------------------------------------- 
Attacker rolls 3 dice   Attacker loses 2 29.26%     Attacker loses 1 34.03%
                        Both lose 1      33.58%     Defender loses 1 65.97%
                        Defender loses 2 37.17%

Attacker rolls 2 dice   Attacker loses 2 44.83%     Attacker loses 1 42.13%
                        Both lose 1      32.41%     Defender loses 1 57.87%
                        Defender loses 2 22.76%
```

**Task**

A **full program** is required which will accept from stdin or commandline, a number of attacking armies and a number of defending armies. There will be at least 1 army of each. Your code will display the number of armies as follows

1.If there is only 1 attacking army, your program shall immediately terminate with the message `Insufficient force.`

2.The code shall now accept a user input **from stdin**. If the user now enters anything other than an empty string, the code shall terminate. If the user enters an empty string, you must simulate the roll of the appropriate number of dice, sort each player's dice in descending order, and report the result and the updated number of armies per example below. 2 trailing newlines are required after the output.

```
Attacker dice: 5 3 1
Defender dice: 5 4

Attacker: p armies (where p is the number of attacking armies)
Defender: q armies (where q is the number of defending armies)
(2 trailing newlines)
```

3.If either player now has 0 armies, display the message `Defender defeated!` or `Attacker defeated!` as appropriate and terminate the program. Similarly, if the attacker now has only 1 army, terminate with the message `Insufficient force.`

The program shall now loop back to step 2 and continue until either one player's armies are depleted or the user enters a non-empty string.

**Rules**

The distribution of the dice throws shall be exactly as with real dice (up to the limits of uniformity both the dice and the random number generator used.) It is expected that most submissions will generate the numbers for each die and then sort them. Clever submissions that generate the output in other ways avoiding the sorting step are acceptable, but the theoretical probability distribution of the output must be identical to the real dice throws. (For example it is permissible to precalculate and presort all 216 possible throws of 3 dice and select one of these at random.)

Due to the real time nature of the application a full program is required, with input from stdin (enabling the user to run quick fire battles by reviewing the output and pressing the return key.)

Formatting of output strings and newlines shall be exactly as described above. Up to 2 additional symbols (but not alphanumerics) are acceptable between and around numbers. For example `[3,2,1]` is an acceptable way of displaying the roll of 3 dice.

**Scoring**

This is code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

***(example output to be added)***

Comment: I don't see the point of requiring termination on a nonempty string.

Comment: @ThomasKwa An attacker doesn't always want to fight to the death, especially if he has a run of bad luck with the dice. The user experience is designed to make attacking as easy as possible but there has to be a way to terminate. The alternative would be `ctrl z` or `ctrl c` which is ugly. If you mean you don't see the point of termination on the first iteration, well that is partly to enable implementation with a `while` loop but mainly to enable the attacker to change his mind right up to the last minute.

Comment: Oh, okay. I wasn't used to seeing practical concerns on code golf questions.

Comment: Your description of the number of dice rolled by the attacker doesn't seem to match the [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf). You say "*The attacker rolls 3 dice (only 2 if he has only 2 armies)*", but the rules say "*You, the attacker, will roll 1,2 or 3 red dice: You must have at least one
more army in your territory than the number of dice you roll*". (There's also the subtle issue of choosing to roll fewer dice than the maximum because you want to keep more than one army behind).

Answer (score 1):

### Help find Mersenne primes! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

There has recently been a discovery of a [new prime number](http://www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M74207281): 2^74207281-1. This is the biggest prime number to date and broke the previous 3-year record holder by over 4 million digits!

Your job will be to help mathematicians find some prime numbers (not really). You must take in an integer `N` and output the `N`th Mersenne prime ([OEIS A000668](https://oeis.org/A000668)). You may assume that the `N`th Mersenne prime is under your languages maximum integer number and/or will not cause an overflow (but your code should work for higher numbers if your language allowed it. You may **not** use any built ins for primality testing and cannot hard-code any values.

You can find a list of most of these numbers over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#List_of_known_Mersenne_primes).

#### Test Cases

```
2 -> 7
5 -> 8191
8 -> 2147483647
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shotest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Please don't call it GIMPS XD.

Comment: 1. Yes, that's the wrong sequence. It's actually A000668. 2. The current wording of the overflow assumption seems to allow hard-coding 4 values if your language operates purely on bytes. I also see no restriction on built-in primality testing.

Comment: I've been thinking about "*[tag:code-golf] or [tag:fastest-code]*". As [tag:code-golf] it's a loop with multiplication by two and a primality test, and primality testing has been done to death. As [tag:fastest-code], it would pretty much be a case of simplifying the GIMPS client to something which could be posted. I suggest that you make it a compromise: [tag:code-golf], but with a speed constraint which rules out naïve primality testing. Maybe write a Lucas-Lehmer test in a slow language, take the highest value it can do in 6 seconds, and require answers to reach that value in 1 minute.

Comment: Somehow failed to find it when I searched before, but [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52152/194) is related.

Answer (score 1):

## Pixel "Density"

In this challenge, we will be viewing each pixel in an image as a particle with two properties:

(1) vertical density (*vd*)

(2) horizontal density (*hd*)

These two properties are determined by the RGB values of the pixel in the following manner:

*vd* = Red - Blue

*hd* = 128 - Green

We call a ***sorted image*** an image that satisfies the following conditions:

For each pixel:

1. no pixel to the right has a lower *hd*
2. no pixel to the left has a higher *hd*
3. no pixel above has a higher *vd*
4. no pixel below has a lower *hd*

The challenge is to produce such sorted images.

**Input**

An image in any "common, recognizable" format, via file or stdin.

**Output**

A sorted image in a "common, recognizable" format (not necessarily the same format as input) containing exactly the pixels of the original , via file or stdout.

**Relevant Details**:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- alpha values (if they exist) are ignored.
- Libraries may be used, but size must be added to your score
- "common, recognizable" formats will be determined by the community. I don't expect this to be an issue, but if you feel the the loose wording is being exploited, downvote the answer (*or even better, help me fix it before the challenge goes live. I don't really want to enumerate the allowed formats, but maybe that is a better option?*).

If there is interest in the question, I will create a reference implementation as well as test cases.

Comment: I don't think this specific task is a dupe - the closest that comes to mind involves doing the same transformation but on colours represented as hex strings rather than on the actual bytes. However, this is pretty much "Look up one value `i` in an array; then loop applying `A[i++]^=255` until the end of the array. Adding alpha makes it slightly less boring, but not much.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You were right about it being extremely boring, I've reworked the challenge considerably. I hope this is more interesting.

Comment: There seem to be 2 separate tasks here: 1. the pixel sorting. 2. processing bmp files. Do you want the file processing to be part of the same challenge? Otherwise you could allow any recognised freely available image format. For example, I would expect code to process a [ppm file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) to be considerably shorter than code to process a bmp file.

Comment: [Relevant meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8077#8077)

Comment: @trichoplax good point. My original thinking was to discourage the use of libraries so I wanted to use the simplest format I could think of, which is bmp. I'll make changes.

Comment: changes made (for future readers of these comments)

Answer (score 1):

## Parse an "Efficient" Encoding

Let us define a fictitious encoding "ENCWID", that follows this general form: there are three bits that denote the length of the following character, for each character. This looks something like this:

```
WWWN..N
   ^^^^--- the actual character
^^^------- width bits; from 000 to 111
```

Perhaps this is a little vague. To understand this better, let us encode the string "Hello!" into ENCWID. Observe:

```
H   72   1001000
e   101  1100101
l   108  1101100
o   111  1101111
!   33   100001
```

This diagrams the binary ASCII codes of each character in the string. Let us put these values into an array that represents "Hello!": `[1001000,1100101,1100101,1100101,1101111,100001]`. The widths for each of these strings are 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, and 6 respectively. To binary, this makes 7 `111` and 6 `110`. Now, we put the binary length of each binary ASCII code before the actual ASCII code, and combine them all into a single string, as such:

```
111-1001000 111-1100101 111-1101100 111-1101100 111-1101111 110-100001
(7)-(  H  ) (7)-(  e  ) (7)-(  l  ) (7)-(  l  ) (7)-(  ᴏ  ) (6)-(  !  )
```

(Spaces, hyphens, and parentheses added for visual clarity.)

And thus, the encoding of "Hello!" is `11110010001111100101111110110011111011001111101111110100001`.

Decoding the string form is perhaps rather easy, using the following steps:

1. Read three characters; call this N.
2. Set N to the decimal number represented by N, from binary.
3. Read the next N charcters; call this S.
4. Parse S as a binary number, and append this character to the result.
5. If there are still unread characters, go to step 1. Otherwise, continue.
6. Return the result.

**Objective** Your objective is to write two programs; one that encodes and one the decodes the described encoding. Your score is the sum of the program's byte count.

---

### Implications

Suppose that we can actually implement this in mainstream use; then, an encoding can be used that utilizes the lower-width codepoints for the most common letters in a given language. This would allow for a lesser amount of bits to convey the same message.

Say we did this for English, and that this

```
earniol1t.9h0s,dC()u2Scmy8gBJDW7HvM6RbkA435wfLPGpTKEFNYO
zI'Vq/Ux-[]jZ"  ;:QX&!
```

is the approximate frequency at which english letters occur, this could be our (partial) encoding:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
0     e  a  r  n  i  o  l  1  t  .  9  h  0  s  ,
1  d  C  (  )  u  2  S  c  m  y  8  g  B  J  D  W
2  7  H  v  M  6  R  b  k  A  4  3  5  w  f  L  P
3  G  p  T  K  E  F  N  Y  O  \n z  I  '  V  q  /
4  U  x  -  [  ]  j  Z  "  \t ;  :  Q  X  &  !  \
```

Thus, "Hello!" would be encoded as:

```
H   12   18   10010     (5 => 101)
e   01   01   1         (1 => 001)
l   07   07   111       (3 => 011)
o   06   06   110       (3 => 011)
!   4E   78   1001110   (7 => 111)

101-10010 001-1  011-111 011-111 011-110 111-1001110
(5)-( H ) (1)(e) (3)-(l) (3)-(l) (3)-(o) (7)-(  !  )

=> 1011001000110111110111110111101111001110
(²7ß{Î, under ISO-8859-7 encoding)
```

And, "Hello!" fits into a clean 5 bytes under this encoding, as opposed to 6-byte standard encoding. This would equate to a lot more bytes saved for a higher sample size.

---

---

## Meta

Suggestions?

Comment: 1. The introduction talks in terms of bits, but the description of decoding talks in terms of characters. Which is it? 2. If it's bits, how is padding to an exact multiple of 8 bits handled? (Or to an exact multiple of some other word size, if the storage/transmission model isn't based on octets). 3. With respect to the implications, see Huffman encoding and arithmetic encoding, which do the same thing better.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Bits, I will revise. 2. I don't know much about this stuff; this really isn't an implementation as it is an interpretation. 3. I didn't claim that this was the best way. >_<. I know of both mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

## Language Guessing

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

(Inspired by [What's the Language?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69920/whats-the-language))

According to the [first Google result](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html), the most popular programming languages are:

1. Java
2. C++
3. C#
4. Python
5. PHP

(For our purposes, C and C++ will both be treated as C++, though the test cases may include C source code and header files)

### Your Task

Write a function that accepts a String, determines what programming language the String is, and returns its result.

### Rules

- The input String will be in one of the five languages listed above.
- Your method should return a String with the name of the programming language exactly as written above.
- Your code must be under **150 bytes**.
- No compiling, running, or otherwise evaluating the test cases to determine their language.
- No standard loopholes.

### Scoring

- The code with the highest match percentage wins
- For every 15 bytes under the 150 byte limit, you get an extra percentage point (a 61-75 byte program would get 5% extra on top of the match percentage.
- The method or function header does not count toward the total byte count. Return statements do count, however.
- The code used to load the test cases and feed them into your method does not count either.
- You get one import for "free". Any other imports count toward the byte limit.

### Test Cases and Testing Code

Here is sample java code used for testing submissions. If you write in a language besides java, your tester must only accept one parameter, and cannot access any variables that are stored between iterations of the function. The entire code, including the tester, must be included in your answer.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tester{

    static int right = 0;//How many are right
    static int total = 0;//How many tested in all

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Opens up test cases
        File rootFolder = new File("./Test Cases");
        File[] subFolders = rootFolder.listFiles();

        HashMap<File, String> fileList = new HashMap<>();

        //Add all files in a subfolder to a HashMap and associate them with the language
        for(File currentFolder : subFolders){
            if(currentFolder.isDirectory()){
                for(File currentFile : currentFolder.listFiles()){
                    fileList.put(currentFile, currentFolder.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        //Iterate through files
        fileList.forEach((File f,String lang)->{
            System.out.print("Testing " + f.getName()+"\t");

            try{
                //Get contents of file
                BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(f));
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
                sc.useDelimiter("\\Z");
                String contents = sc.next();

                //Call compute method and store result
                String result = compute(contents);

                //Increment counters
                if(result.equals(lang))
                    right++;
                total++;

                System.out.println("Guess: " + result +"\tActual: " + lang);
            } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("There was an error when reading the file");
            }
        });

        //Print out final results
        System.out.println("Right: " + right);
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Percent: " + (double)right * 100.0 / total + "%");
    }

    public static String compute(String c){
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

The test cases consist of 500 code samples (100 from each language) from around the internet (mostly github). Specific locations can be found in `Credit.txt` in the Test Cases folder.

The test cases can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpb9771ilmap0r3/Language%20Guessing.zip?dl=0).

Comment: If you don't want to limit it to Java, don't enforce the submission tester.  Most languages aren't too hard to test, with the exception of TinyMUSH.

Comment: @RikerW I made the wording a bit more language neutral.

Comment: Why do we need a tester at all?  Can't we just test it manually?

Comment: How else would you run through a few hundred test cases

Comment: @Downgoat's was a special case, normally there aren't that many test cases.  There should only be like 10 different cases, and that should cover most of it.

Comment: The number of test cases will vary widely with the challenge. Depending on the length of the code samples in this challenge, I can imagine a fairly large number of test cases being used to give a demanding challenge.

Comment: If the test cases are provided as a list of inputs and a list of outputs, would that allow for easy testing in any language? Simply automate the running of the candidate answer against every input, giving a list of outputs, and then compare that with the target list of outputs.

Comment: The test cases are a bunch of files of each programming language. They are sorted into subfolders with the name of the language the example is written in. The tester loads each file, gets the language based on the subfolder's name, puts the whole file into a string, and feeds it to the method. It compares the returned value to the subfolder's name. This way, to add or change test cases, it's a matter of dropping additional files into a folder, or dropping in a folder to add a new language.

Answer (score 1):

### Semaphore Decoder

You are to write a program which can decode ASCII semaphores.  Each semaphore fits in a 3x2 grid, with the flagger's head represented by a `o` (which is always in the upper middle square), and his flags represented by `_ | / \`.  Each block is separated by one blank column.  Text may continue onto additional lines if it gets too long.  The letters look like the following format:

```
[Space]  o   A  o  B _o  C \o  D |o  E o/  F o_  G o   H _o  I \o  J |o_
        | |    /|     |     |     |    |     |     |\    /      /       

K  o|  L  o/  M  o_  N  o   O _o\  P _o|  Q _o/  R _o_  S _o   T \o|
  /      /      /      / \                                  \

U \o/   V |o   W /o_  X o/  Y \o_  Z o_
            \           \             \
```

To keep your messages from being observed by spies, your code must be as short as possible.

Example:

**Input**

```
_o| _o_ _o\  o   o   o_  o_ \o   o   o   o  _o| \o/  o_  o_  o/  o/ _o   o
             |\ /|  /   /    /  / \  |\ | |           \   \ /    |    \ | |
 o   o  |o   o  \o  _o\ |o   o/  o   o   o/ _o\  o/  o_
/|  / \  |  | |  |       |   |  | |  |\ /       /    |
```

**Output**

```
PROGRAMMING PUZZLES AND CODE GOLF
```

Comment: Essentially the opposite of this encoder -- http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3628/42963

Comment: @TimmyD - I saw that.  In fact I deliberately chose a different format (3x2 instead of 3x3) so that you couldn't just use the same code in reverse.  I think the bonuses will also make this a bit more interesting, since some signals have multiple meanings, and you need to keep a stack to handle the Error code.

Comment: [-1 for bonuses](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/45941)

Comment: @Mego - Is it the idea of bonuses that offends you?  Or is the scoring just not balanced?  I think the bonuses are what make this challenge the most interesting.  Would it help if I were to make them requirements instead?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The linked post explains fairly well why I am strongly against bonuses. The biggest issue I have is that `n` bonuses require people to solve the problem `2^n` different ways, and look for the best score. The bonuses add unneede complexity, and detract from the actual challenge.

Comment: If you think the bonuses make it more interesting, make them requirements.

Comment: What I don't get is - I've seen dozens of challenges that had one or more bonuses, and I've never seen a complaint about them until now.  I guess I could see how it affects some languages more than others, but it's not like there's actual prize-money going out for these things.  It's more just a matter of having fun and practicing code-fu.  I'm just afraid that having those bonuses as a requirement might scare off some people from even trying.  But without them - is this even much of a challenge for the veterans out there?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Bonuses on challenges used to be rarer. Then people started putting bonuses on everything, with severely detracted from challenge quality. So, in response, the community decided (in the post I linked) that bonuses shouldn't be used unless you have a really strong justification for including them. 9 times out of 10, the challenge would be vastly improved by making them requirements or discarding them outright.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows batch polyglot/hybrids challenge with any language possible**
/* I need some help to refine my challenge */

As the batch scripts are pretty limited, hybrid files that embed a code from another language into a batch file are used a lot lately.

Though usually  there are some requirements for a good hybrid script:

1. The embedded code should be usable as-it-is - without any ugly batch escaping sequences.
2. There should not be redundant output. E.g. a lot of languages use **/* */** for multi-line comments. If the batch script executes a line that starts with **/ *** it will print an error message an will continue to the next line .Though it will allow you to hybridize C/C++/C#/Java/...  with a batch file  the error message cannot be surpassed so this will not count as a good hybrid.
3. No temp files.It's easy to output a lot of code into a temp file that will be later executed , the IO operations will slow the script and on of the main advantages of batch scripting (the speed) will be lost. And more over is a challenging constraint. But this will be not possible for compiling languages and for extension sensitive languages.

Some examples will follow:

[JScript](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/b8q29_uLfQs) (good for example as it comes with every windows installation) technique invented somewhere in the link by Tom Lavedas :

```
@if (true == false) @end /*
@echo off
cscript //nologo //e:javascript "%~dpnx0" %*
echo Output from the batch.
goto :EOF */

WScript.Echo('Output from the jscript.');
```

The output will be:

> Output from the jscript.
>
> Output from the batch.

The technique uses the JScript (javascript has no such thing) specific **@** directives to make the code valid (or silent) both for both languages.

Another example (again with JScript) invented by [Ryan Biesemeyer](https://gist.github.com/yaauie/959862):

```
0</* :
@echo off
echo Output from the batch.
cscript /nologo /E:jscript %~f0 %*
exit /b %errorlevel%
*/0;

WScript.Echo('Output from the jscript.');
```

This time is used the redirection priority in batch scripts and `0</* :` will be parsed as `0:</*` .

Here are some info that can help you:

- every line that starts with **@** will be silent - even the invalid commands.
- every line that starts with **:** will be taken as label in batch and will be not executed
- every line that starts with something like `<someWord : someWord` will be silent because of redirection priority
- every line that starts with something like `digit<someWord : someWord` will be silent because of redirection priority (this time the output will be redirected to a stream).In this case will be best to use **0**
- you can use `<space><tab> ; , =` at the beginning of every line - these will be ignored as standard delimiters in batch.Can be useful if some language use some of these as comment.
- if you start a line with `%not_existing_variable%` it will be replaced with nothing.Could be useful if in some language comments start with percent.
- If you finish a line with a caret `^` the next line will be appended at the end.With the caret in batch you can escape the new line.

here's a little bit more [inspiration](http://dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6931)

And here's the challenge. Your script should be with `.bat` or `.cmd` extension . It should contain a code from another language - the code should be used by the second language as it is (no escapes symbols)  .REPL tools are accepted with the condition of no escape symbols - except in the line where the REPL tool is invoked. There should not be redundant output. There should be not temp files (with the exception of compiling languages , and file extension sensitive languages - then the file should copy itself in the %TEMP% folder).

Each script should accept one command line argument which will be printed 5 (five) times . Both from the batch part of the code and from the second language prefixed by the language name (for the batch case it should be `BATCH:` for example.If the second language is Ruby it should be `RUBY:`)

For sure this will be not possible with every language , but for many it is achievable.

The winner should propose the most solutions with different languages (or if the language is the same a different kind of techniques should be used like in the two examples above).In case of equal number of solutions the first one wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Weekly Physics Golf #{TBD}: Wavelength of a Sound Wave [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

***META NOTE: I believe, and others in the comments, that this challenge is quite trivial. So, I will be working on making this challenge harder in the next few days.***

### Introduction to the Series

Every week I will be posting a physics challenge. My goal here is to design challenges that in the end, teach some people some physics. Overall, the challenges will be very basic with little information. All of these challenges will have the minimal information necessary to solve them, and the goal is for users like you to do some research, watch some videos, and understand how these concepts work to teach you how to approach these types of physics problems and explain how they work. Of course, I will also give two optional hints per challenge, which are there if you do not have the time or determination to do the research, or you cannot figure out how to do the problem after researching. The two hints will be "necessary equations for this challenge" and "process to solve the problem". The hints are completely optional to use and it is encourages to not use them, but as stated above to learn the information for yourself. The series will have one main leaderboard. Whoever has the least combined byte count for all of the challenges gets a *to be determined* prize. Each challenge will range in difficulty, with an upwards trend of difficulty. I wish you all luck and I hope you learn a thing or two!

### Challenge #{TBD}: Wavelength of a Sound Wave (Difficulty: EASY)

Many people may not know that sound is actually a wave, which would explain why it can go through objects and bend around corners. But it has some really interesting properties. For example, the speed of the sound wave changes from a few factors, all relating to the medium it travels through. In this challenge, you will have to figure out the wavelength of a sound wave through a given medium.

But first, lets define a medium. A medium is any liquid, solid, or gas that a wave can travel through. Mediums can affect the speed of a sound wave in two ways: the ***density*** of the medium, and the ***bulk modulus elasticity*** of the medium. But what are these two things? Well lets first consider the density of an object. Density is defined to be the *mass* divided *volume* of the object, or in simple terms, *amount of mass in a given space*. This is important, as waves travel differently through mediums of different densities. The reason behind this is that a medium with a higher density has more inertia (the resistance to change in motion). An object with a higher inertia will be more difficult to move with a wave (which displaces particles to move). Therefore, **INCREASED DENSITY corresponds to DECREASED WAVE SPEED**.

Now lets define *bulk modulus elasticity*. This is really just a fancy name for *stiffness of an object*. But what does this have to do with anything? Well, when an object is stiffer, each molecule is more interconnected to other molecules. And because a wave displaces particles to "move", it will move through a stiff medium faster because it can move larger molecules, hence moving more distance in a shorter time, a.k.a. moving faster. Therefore, **INCREASED BULK MODULUS ELASTICITY corresponds to INCREASED WAVE SPEED**.

So in this challenge, I will give you the *density* and the *BME* (bulk modulus elasticity) of the medium, and also the frequency of the sound wave. Your job is to use this information and output the wavelength. Here are the full specs:

- Input will be three *numbers* (not necessarily integers). They correspond to *density* in `kg/m^3`, *bulk modulus elasticity* in Pascals, and *sound wave frequency* in hertz.
- Input can be in any order, in any convenient format (so `12.3 45.6 78.9`, `[12.3 45.6 78.9]`, and `78.9,[12.3,45.6]` are all acceptable).
- You may assume that input will never cause any sort of error during execution.
- Output will be the calculated frequency of the sound wave in meters, precise to *three decimal places*, omitting leading and trailing zeros. For example, inputs of `6`, `27`, and `3` would given an output of `0.707` after rounding from `0.70710678118654752440084436210485`.
- Shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases

***META NOTE: Test cases to come, I am working on them right now.***

### Hints

These hints are for those who do not want to put in the time and effort of research, or those who could not find a solution. So, here are the two hints:

#### Hint 1: Equations

You need the following equations for this challenge:

> [image]

#### Hint 2: Sample Solution Process:

> Using the two equations above, we can set them equal to each other to get:
>
> [image]
>
> Solving for wavelength gets us this equation:
>
> [image]
>
> From here you can just plug in values.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

### Leaderboard

***Meta note: blah blah blah, working leaderboard will eventually go here! This leaderboard will contain and combine scores for all of the weekly challenges. It will only be visible on this question, though.***

Comment: Please tell me of any suggestions, I'll be happy to hear them. More importantly, please alert me of any mathematical inaccuracies and/or inaccurate explanations.

Comment: +1 for the idea. I love learning new things!

Comment: But my concern with *this* challenge is that it's too simple and straight-forward. The shortest answer in every language would be something like `(a,b,c)=>(b/a)**.5/c` (except for Mathematica, it proabably has a built-in :P ).

Comment: I concur with @user81655, but I'm excited to see what you can come up with.

Comment: @user81655 Yes, after further analysis I have realized how simple the problem is. I am currently working on an alternative challenge while I make this one more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I've posted two well-received (by my standards: 10+ no downvotes) questions in the past; however, I've always missed a bit of information, so I welcome all feedback to this challenge!</sub>

#### Introduction

A palindrome is a word or string of words that is the same forwards as it is backwards, e.g. taco cat, kayak, madam im adam. I'm sure by now you're all familiar with [palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome).

An anagram is a word or group of words that when the letters are rearranged, forms a different word or string of words. If you haven't already, Google for [*anagram*](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=anagram) or [*define anagram*](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20anagram&es_th=1) (not part of the puzzle, obviously).

#### Task

Your task is to write a program which will take a string of lowercase characters and blank space, and return truthy/falsey if the string can be anagrammed into (or *is*) a palindrome (even if it doesn't form a legit word). This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins. [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

#### Input

- A string of at least 1 character containing a mixture of lowercase alphanumeric characters and blank space
- Whitespace can be ignored when determining whether a word or phrase can be anagrammed.

#### Output

- [Truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)

#### Examples:

**Truthy**
kayak = kayak / akyka
maam = maam / amma
her taco cat hero = hertacoocatreh
boob = obbo
boobs = bosob
ooh = oho
lol = lol (already a palindrome)
zzz = zzz (already a palindrome)
i = i
00010001 = 10000001
0xd00000d = 0d00x00d0
sevens 7even = seven7neves
**Falsey**
glum glow worm
maam im adam
book
banana
nana ant
jquery

Comment: What whitespace characters can appear in the input? And the rule that "*anagrammed into a palindrome*" requires the palindrome to be distinct from the original string, even if that were itself a palindrome, should be mentioned in the task description, not hidden in the examples.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback: I removed the unnecessary "palindrome must be unique from original" requirement, and clarified whitespace.

Comment: I actually thought that the requirement to be different to the original string, while needing to be stated clearly because it was unexpected, made the question more interesting. Without that requirement the test is just that there's at most one non-whitespace character which occurs an odd number of times. Although I suppose that with a permutation operator the difference isn't that big.

Comment: Not quite: _na na na na_ can be anagrammed into the palindrome _nanaanan_ and it only contains characters with even counts.

Comment: I said "*at most one*", not "*exactly one*".

Answer (score 1):

**Maximum cover time ratio**

Given an undirected graph and a start node, there is an expected number of steps to reach all possible nodes if you walk at random. This expected number of steps will depend on which node you start from. For a given graph and starting node, let us call the number of steps to visit all nodes in the graph the `cover time`. We can estimate the `cover time` by just setting off 1000 walks and taking the average.

You can also set off two independent random walks from the same node at once and see how many steps it takes for every node to be visited by at least one of the walks. Clearly you can do this with more than two as well. Let us call the expected number of steps to reach each node with at least one of `k` random walks starting from the same node, the `k-cover time`. We can see that `cover time = 1-cover time`.

**Task**

Write code that explores different undirected graphs, starting nodes and values of k and computes both the cover time and the k-cover time for each.  You should use at least 1000 random walks to estimate the time to reach all nodes.  The goal is to maximize the expected cover time ratio explained below.

**Output**

Your code should output a single graph in any sensible format you choose, the value `k`, the identity of a starting node, the cover time and the `k-cover` time.

**Score**

Your score will be  `cover time` from your given starting node divided by k times `k-cover time` starting from the same node.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any language or library you like (that wasn't designed for this challenge). However, for the purposes of scoring I will run your code on my machine so please provide clear instructions for how to run it on Ubuntu.

**My Machine** The timings will be run on my machine. This is a standard Ubuntu install on an 8GB AMD FX-8350 Eight-Core Processor.  This also means I need to be able to run your code.

## Details

- I will kill your code after 2 minutes unless it starts to run out of memory before then. Your code should therefore output something before 2 minutes is up.

---

Any help with finishing this question would be gratefully received. I think it just needs examples and test cases and maybe a picture or two.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: Shouldn't the k-cover time be the same as the cover time by the central limit theorem?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe my definition is confusing but you can explore a city more quickly with two people rather than one.  Similarly, you would expect to explore a graph more quickly with two random walks rather than one.  The number of steps is measured until every node has been visited by at least one random walk.

Comment: Aha. I think the *at least one* belongs in the definitional statement: "*expected number of steps to reach each node with at least one of k random walks starting from the same node*". Have you done any testing on small cases to see whether there are easy unbounded solutions or easy bounds?

Comment: What's the input to the program going to be?

Comment: @feersum There wasn't going to be any input in a similar fashion to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/find-the-largest-gap-between-good-primes .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can actually solve this problem analytically as questions like those are known under the name *Markov Chains*. You can e.g. calculate the expected number of steps from A to B by making B absorbing, and calculate the expected number of steps to absorbtion.

Comment: @flawr That would be very interesting.  As I can't I hope an expert can comment on this.

Comment: I'm not very fluent anymore but I'm going to reread some of [this](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter11.pdf) which I found very helpful in the past.

Answer (score 1):

## Wring the changes

I want to ring Stedman Doubles, but I'm lazy so I want to get to a particular change and back as quickly as possible.

Change-ringing is essentially an enumeration of permutations of a set of small integers. To make the enumeration ringable, no bell can move more than one step in each permutation. A change therefore consists of some or all of the bells swapping places with adjacent bells.

Consider the case of five bells. Before changes start, the bells are rung in ascending numerical order, known as Rounds, which would be `12345`. A typical change would then consist of leaving one bell in the same place while a double swap occurs between the remaining four bells, thus the name "Doubles". The bell that remains in the same place serves to notate the change. Note that this refers to the bell currently in that position, rather than the bell with that number.

In the case of Stedman the full notation is `3.1.5.3.1.3.1.3.5.1.3.1`. If you repeat those 12 changes five times you will enumerate 60 changes before returning to Rounds. The first few changes are as follows:

```
[12345 Rounds]
 21354 (1,2 and 4,5 swap)
 23145 (1,3 and 5,4 swap; 2 was 1st so doesn't move)
 32415 (2,3 and 1,4 swap)
 23451 (3,2 and 1,5 swap; 4 was 3rd so doesn't move)
```

There are of course 120 permutations of five bells, so in order to access the other 60 changes, or simply for variety, Stedman allows for every sixth change to be altered by a call known as a Single, which causes the two bells currently in position 4 and 5 to stay in the same place instead of exchanging as they would normally do.

A touch is described by a sequence of letters describing whether each sixth change is Plain or a Single. It ends when it returns to Rounds, which need not be after a multiple of six changes, but it may not repeat any change, so 120 is the longest possible length of a touch of Stedman Doubles. For instance, a complete extent of all 120 changes could be rung using the touch `PPPPPPPPPSPPPPPPPPPS`.

Your challenge is to write a program or function that will calculate the shortest touch that includes a given change. Your input should be the change (you can expect it to be a valid change) as a string, and your output should be (in either order) the touch description (as a string of P and S characters) and also the number of changes (including the final rounds, so up to 120).

The score for this challenge shall be the length of your program, plus the lengths of the touches it finds for the following inputs:

```
13524
14235
14253
43215
53124
```

The Batch script `@echo 120 PPPPPPPPPSPPPPPPPPPS` would therefore score 630.

Comment: This could use a little background information. Ideally, the challenge should be self-contained and understandable by somebody who does not know what *Stedman Doubles* or *change ringing* is (such as myself).

Comment: So in essence, we have a highly structured digraph of 60 vertices (corresponding to the order-60 group generated by P and S, which I assume is A5 but haven't checked); each of the 120 edges is labelled with 12 permutations (and each permutation therefore occurs on 12 edges, but symmetry), and we need to find the shortest cycle from 12345 which includes an edge labelled with the input permutation

Comment: @PeterTaylor Close. You don't need a cycle as long as you reach the input permutation before you reach an edge labelled 12345 (or 12345 is labelled after the input on the same edge), and there are 4 generators as the meaning of P alternates between 42351 and 43152 and S between 42315 and 43125, so the group is generated by P1P2, P1S2, S1P2 and S1S2 (but I don't know what the group looks like, except that (P1P2)^5==I).

Answer (score 1):

## Show me your OOP

[popularity-contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contests)

Your task is to implement OOP that have this feature:

1. Inheritance (Single dispatch)
2. Class

Your submission have to translate this pseudo-code into your languages:

```
class Animal{
    Animal(string name){
        printLn("An animal has summoned " + name);
    }
    public void sound();
}
class Sheep extends Animal{
    bool woolstate;
    Sheep(bool state){
        woolstate = state;
    }
    public void sound(){
        printLn("Mbaaaa\n");
    }
    public void growWool(){
        woolstate = true;
    }
    public void getWool(){
        if(woolstate == true){
            printLn("Mbaaaa\nget " + (new Math.Random()).getInt(0, 10).toString() + " bags of wool");
            woolstate = false;
        }
    }
}
class Worm(){
    Worm tails;
    public int numbers;
    public Worm(int number, int length){
        if(length != 0){
            tails = new Worm(number, length-1);
        }
        numbers = number;
        if(number == length){
            this.privateMethod
        }
    }
    public Worm getTails(){
        return this.tails;
    }
    public Worm setTails(Worm tail){
        this.tails = tail
    }
    public Worm getNumbers(){
        return this.numbers;
    }
    public Worm setNumbers(int number){
        this.numbers = number
    }
    public void sound(){
        printLn("Doesn't sound");
    }
    private void privateMethod(){
        printLn("This is a private method");
    }
}
int main(){
    Sheep a = new Sheep(true);
    Animal b = new Sheep(false);
    Worm c = new Worm(5, 5);
    b.sound();
    a.sound();
    b.getWool(); //Error
    a.getWool();
    if(c.getNumbers()==5){
        c.setNumbers(6);
    }
    b=c.getTails();
    b.setNumber(7); //Error
    b.sound();
}
```

If the random function is not available, you can deterministically return anything from 0 into 10.

The submission should be scored based on:

1. Difficulty of implementation (i.e. how far is the language from OOP?)
2. Ease of usage of implemetation
3. Efficiency of implementation
4. The pleasantness of syntax

Comment: This could be a potential challenge! However, it could use more objective criteria, as [tag:popularity-contest]s are now [generally frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8134/33208) here. For example, what prevents me from posting a 0-byte C#/Java/C++/etc. answer, and claiming that it implements OOP? (Also, some languages don't have a random feature for the `Sheep.getWool()` function.) *Also*, we apparently need an interface feature as well, for `Animal.sound()`, and is the `Sheep` constructor supposed to call the `Animal` constructor? If so, you forgot to call it with a name.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 What is your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

## Prove that this program terminates or run forever

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

### Introduction:

Halting problem has been shown to have no complete algorithm. Yet it is important to understand what the program does and verifying the program if the program matches with its specification

## Challenger

### Challenges

Your challenge is to write program that takes no input in given language (so no obscure language is used) and a formal proof that the program is halting or run forever. Output will be ignored.

### Rules

1. Proof must be written formally.
2. No computer aided proof. (i.e. running the program, or convert it into Coq, Idris, or another dependent-typed language)
3. This is not [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) challenge, so do not obscure the program.
4. If your program is not cracked after 6 days, then you must give the proof whether your program halts or not. It is then verified.
5. Your program should not depend on unsolved problems.
6. Cracking your own submission is not allowed.
7. Score for submission:

   - Cracked  : -5
   - Verified : 10
   - Flawed   : -15

## Prover

### Challenges

Your challenge is to proof that the program that is posted in Challenger thread is halting or run forever.

### Rules

1. Proof must be written formally.
2. No computer aided proof. (i.e. running the program, or convert it into Coq, Idris, or another dependent-typed language)
3. Score for submission:

   - Verified (With no proof from owner)     : 8
   - Verified (With flawed proof from owner) : 12
   - Flawed                                  : -8

## Sandbox Question

What language should I use? The requirement is:

1. Turing Complete
2. Imperative
3. Easy to understand, even to noncoder
4. Easy to write

Also, I need help with the leaderboard

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: as i understand it, the robber doesn't actually write any code, huh?

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I don't know which from Prover and Challenge is the robber?

Comment: This is unfeasible. If I write a program that stops when it disproves the Goldbach conjecture, no one here (including me) is going to know if it stops or loops forever (without becoming instantly world famous).

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies You have to provide proof after 6 days. If not, the submission will not be safe and you will not get score at all.

Comment: It becomes really a question of who can find the most obscure mathematical result which can be translated into code rather than a programming contest *per se*.

Answer (score 1):

## Continue the sequence

[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

As we all know, there are a lot of integer sequences in the world. What if we could create one program to figure out the next few items in any given sequence? That would be pretty cool, right? Well, I'm pretty sure we can't create a program that does *every* sequence, but we can at least do most of the simple ones.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program or function that takes in 5 integers in any reasonable format (array, string, separate arguments, etc.), and returns/outputs the next 5 integers in the sequence.

### Rules

- Your submission must be deterministic; that is, the output should be the same every time for the same input.
- You may not use a built-in for determining the next items. (*cough* Mathematica *cough*)

### Scoring

To score a submission:

1. Take the value of each single output integer minus the expected output.
2. Take the square root of the absolute value of each of these.
3. Take the average of the result and add one.
4. Multiply your byte count by this number.

For example, if the only test case were `1,2,3,4,5 => 6,7,8,9,10`, and your 15-byte submission outputs `6,7,8,10,6`, your score would be:

```
1,2. abs(6 - 6) = 0, sqrt(0) = 0
     abs(7 - 7) = 0, sqrt(0) = 0
     abs(8 - 8) = 0, sqrt(0) = 0
     abs(10 - 9) = 1, sqrt(1) = 1
     abs(7 - 10) = 4, sqrt(4) = 2
3.   0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 = 3
     3 / 5 = 0.6; 0.6 + 1 = 1.6
4.   15 bytes * 1.6 = 24
```

Thus, your score would be **24**.

**Lowest score wins.**

### Test cases

```
2,2,2,2,2 => 2,2,2,2,2
1,2,3,4,5 => 6,7,8,9,10
109,117,125,133,141 => 149,157,165,173,181
1,2,4,8,16 => 32,64,128,256,512
1,10,100,1000,10000 => 100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000
1,2,3,5,8 => 13,21,34,55,89
2,1,3,4,7 => 11,18,29,47,76
1,3,6,10,15 => 21,28,36,45,55
1,4,9,16,25 => 36,49,64,81,100
8,7,6,5,4 => 3,2,1,0,-1
1,0,1,0,1 => 0,1,0,1,0
1,2,3,2,1 => 2,3,2,1,2
512,256,128,64,32 => 16,8,4,2,1
1,11,111,1111,11111 => 111111,1111111,11111111,111111111,1111111111
1,21,321,4321,54321 => 654321,7654321,87654321,987654321,10987654321
1,2,6,24,120 => 720,5040,40320,362880,3628800
```

I will create a GitHub Gist with all of the test cases before posting.

## Sandbox questions

Currently, I'm looking for suggestions for:

- a better name
- more tags
- more sequences

Feel free to post any other questions/notes you have.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This will be replaced with the actual number of test cases when this is posted.</sup>

Comment: Why the 100 byte limit?

Comment: @nimi The goal is to correctly predict as many sequences as possible while keeping the code fairly short. Does 100 bytes sound too short?

Comment: ... well, 100 bytes of Pyth aren't 100 bytes of Java. Wordy languages will be quite handicapped.

Comment: @nimi True. How might I be able to fix this?

Comment: Classical bonuses (although discouraged now) work better when relative compared to absolute. Maybe something like `byte count * (2 - percentage solved)`, i.e. 2x bytes if 0%, 1x bytes if 100%, lowest score wins. But somehow we must prevent trivial answers like outputting the constant string `0 0 0 0 0` for 2x9 = 18 bytes.

Comment: Sequences are pretty arbitrary, so I'm having trouble seeing how this could go well. I get the feeling most submissions will just end up hardcoding in a set number of patterns, eg geometric progression, polynomial interpolation, and ignore ones which are too complex, eg Golomb. Also, standard loophole, but it might be worth mentioning explicitly that looking up things on, eg OEIS, is not okay.

Comment: @Sp3000 You have a good point there. What would you think about A) choosing a select number of sequence types, B) choosing a select number of types *and* making it code-golf, or C) just choosing a single type to focus on?

Comment: I had a think about this, and I think what this challenge might need is 1) A fairly large test-battery covering a large variety of sequence types (e.g. OEIS), and 2) A tweak to the scoring system which takes into account how far off a number is (since getting 0 points for a guess that's just off by 1 seems a bit harsh). Just a thought though.

Comment: Regarding your options, I'm not a great fan of C since it changes the challenge completely, and might need dupe checking. There's no real need to limit the number of sequence types I think, as long as there's an incentive to be close with the guess rather than dead on.

Comment: Perhaps make it a [test-battery] with lots of test cases. That seems like the best way to score these types of languages. You may also want to disallow built-ins as I know Mathematica has a built-in to do this

Comment: @Sp3000 Yes, those are some very good thoughts. This is now a test-battery challenge, and the new scoring algorithm takes into account both the byte-count and the average of the sqrt-distances of the outputs. Does this seem like a decent way to score this challenge?

Comment: @Downgoat This is now a test-battery challenge, and built-ins have been banned. Thanks!

Comment: @nimi The scoring system has been completely rewritten.

Comment: With respect to limiting the types of sequence, you need to be careful not to turn it into a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3485/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

### Implement floating-point square-root with integer addition, subtraction and bit-shifts only

Someone has broken your favourite language! *Almost* all arithmetic functions are now unusable. You've been left with integer addition, subtraction, bit-shifts (both left and right) and bitwise operators (AND, XOR, OR, NOT) only. If your language doesn't have bit-shifts you may substitute `*2^i` or `/2^i` for a cost of *i* each time. You need to write an efficient square-root function because it's been proven<sup>[citation needed]</sup> that every useful program uses square-root<sup>[dubious-discuss]</sup>.

Your function will take one number (see format below), calculate its square-root and return the result. The last binary digit may either be consistently rounded down, or rounded to closest.

Rounding down:

```
...0(0)  ...0
...0(1)  ...0
...1(0)  ...1
...1(1)  ...1
```

Rounding to closest:

```
...0(0)  ...0
...0(1)  ...1
...1(0)  ...1
..01(1)  ..10, etc.
```

Scoring:

- 1: Copy an integer (any length)
- 2: Add or Increment
- 2: Subtract or Decrement
- 1: Greater-than, Less-than, Equal-to, etc.
- 1: Check a bit
- 1: Write a bit
- 1: Bit-shift (left or right) by 1
- 2: Bitwise operator (AND, XOR, OR, NOT)
- n x (code + condition): Do-While
- n x condition + (n - 1) x code: While (For can be implemented as While)
- 0 (free): Jump to start or end of loop
- 0 (free): Jump to start of function
- 0 (free): Return from function

Since different languages use different number formats, the format used for scoring this challenge is as follows: 8 bits for the exponent, 32 bits for the mantissa. You don't have to use these lengths internally, just assume this is what it is for scoring purposes.

There will be no negative numbers or zero in the input, nor will you have to store a value of `0.0`. Since the square root function always produces a number closer to 1, you don't need to worry about overflow or underflow. The Most Significant Bit of the mantissa will always be 1.

- All floating point numbers will be stored and passed around as two unsigned integers, *m* and *e*
- *B<sub>m</sub>* and *B<sub>e</sub>* are the number of bits in *m* and *e* respectively
- The value of the number is given by
  2<sup>(*e*-*B<sub>m</sub>*-2<sup>*B<sub>e</sub>*-1</sup>)</sup>*m* or `2^(e-Bm-2^(Be-1))*m`
- In your code *B<sub>m</sub>* must be ≥ 32 and *B<sub>e</sub>* must be ≥ 8

The code will be scored assuming that *B<sub>m</sub>* = 32 and *B<sub>e</sub>* = 8, so no penalty will be given if your code uses larger values.

```
 exponent   MSB          mantissa           LSB    decimal
[01111110] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   0.125
[01111111] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   0.25
[10000000] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   0.5
[10000001] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   1
[10000001] [10100000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   1.25
[10000010] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   2
[10000010] [11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   3
[10000011] [11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   7
[10000100] [10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   8
[10000100] [10010000 00000000 00000000 00000000]   9
```

Please include a version number for ease of reference. If you know the name of your method, please include it too, e.g. "Brute force", "Trial and error", etc. Increase the major number if your score changes, otherwise increase the minor number if your score is the same, e.g:

> **v1.0: Perl, Brute force - 108
>
> v1.1: Perl, Brute force - 108
>
> v1.2: Perl, Brute force - 108
>
> v2.0: Perl, Brute force - 95
>
> v2.1: Perl, Brute force - 95
>
> v3.0: Perl, Brute force - 93**

This is **not** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you will be scored on the efficiency of your algorithm. If more than one answer is equally efficient, the oldest one will be in the lead. If editing your answer reduces your score, it also resets your time. The time is taken from your last minor version 0.

[fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)

---

I'll probably need some fair test values that don't allow tuning for specific numbers.

Thoughts?

Comment: The nested superscript/subscript is hard to read. Can you pull out the offset?

Comment: [Someone has broken your favourite language](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/make-your-language-unusable/)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Cute! The difference is that now your job is to fix it afterwards!

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor. Do you have any other suggestions? Does my scoring seem balanced? Have I forgotten any operations that might be needed? I've never done a [tag:fastest-algorithm] challenge before so I want to make sure it is good.

Comment: [Do X without Y challenges are generally frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/45941)

Comment: @Mego `This isn't always bad`, `"Do X without Y" can be good questions`. Do you think this challenge isn't "meaty" enough? Please don't pigeon-hole it with a broad generality if you don't have specific gripes. If you think the entire concept is flawed, please clearly explain why.

Comment: @CJDennis I never said that I thought the challenge was flawed. I just wanted to point out that challenges of this type are generally frowned upon, and thus you may face some resistance/downvotes with this one.

Comment: @Mego OK. Understood. This is why I've posted it to the Sandbox first. I've had an upvote and no downvotes so far, and while no-one's said "This is brilliant!" no-one's panned it either. Any suggestions you have for improving it/making it more user friendly are welcome!

Comment: Is the unusual [exponent bias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) intentional? What rounding is permitted? It's probably worth explicitly stating that since sqrt is always nearer to one, there's no need to worry about underflow or overflow in the output.

Comment: That floating-point format looks suspiciously like that on the ZX81, which is convenient, as I actually wrote a fast floating point square root for it. If only I could remember it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Are you saying the bias is strange because it doesn't have a `-1`? This _is_ intentional as I believe it will make some methods easier without penalising others.

Comment: @Neil The format is based on the Amstrad CPC (but not identical), so I wouldn't be at all surprised if the format was similar or identical to the ZX81 (both using Z80 CPUs). As I remember a lot of software was easily ported between them.

Comment: I wasn't thinking it through enough. The `-Bm` is because of the implicit binary point in the explanation I'm more used to seeing. Ignore that point.

Answer (score 1):

## Compress by Replacement [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You are to take an input string, and then turn it into another string with a list of replacements which would turn this new string into the input string. The catch is that you must output the smallest such alternate string + list of replacements you can.

The input string will be restricted to the following characters (Please note there is a space at the end and that semicolons are not allowed):

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:<=>?@[]^_`{|}~
```

The way the output is formatted is

`CompressedString;tofind;toreplace;tofind;toreplace;...`

An example output is
`111222;1;abcd;2;efgh` which outputs `abcdabcdabcdefghefghefgh`

The replacement rules are applied in the order they are shown in the output to avoid ambiguity.

Therefore, if one were to input `abcdabcdabcdefghefghefgh` (which has a length of 24). Then the output would be `111222;1;abcd;2;efgh` with a length of 20 which is the shortest possible output for this input

Some other notes:

- The replacement rules are restricted to the same character set that the input has. This means that if the input contained every possible letter except for the character `h`, then your replacement rule would only work if the `tofind` part of the rule is `h`
- There may be situations where the input string is the shortest possible output, this is fine
- The program doesn't have to be computationally efficient, as long as it does calculate the correct answer when it finishes, then it is valid
- There are also occasionally multiple correct answers, any solution which has the smallest possible count is valid and you only need to output one solution, not all the valid solutions
- The semicolons are included in the character count for the output

Some test cases:

```
'abcdabcdabcdabcdefghefghefghefgh' -> '11110000;1;abcd;0;efgh' or '00001111;1;efgh;0;abcd'
'this is a test. this is a test.' -> '0 0;0;this is a test.'
'there is no shortening in this one' -> 'there is no shortening in this one'
'01001001010100101010110101010101010110101010' -> '202030321332130;3;222;2;01' or '22331131210113;3;212;2;010' or '22212233230132;3;121;2;010' or '223233133301132;3;21;2;010' or '222323133310133;3;12;2;010' or '020203031332132;3;222;2;10'
```

This is codegolf, so shortest answer in bytes wins

## Sandbox notes:

- This takes a long time to brute force for anything longer than 40 characters with repeated substrings, so it may take a while for brute forced solutions to verify they are correct. Because of this, I was thinking this question might be better proposed as a "best algorithm" kind of puzzle to see who can make the best algorithm. What do you think?
- Should I allow people to choose what delimiter is used to separate the output? Ideally what would happen is that they would just say 'I am assuming that `,` is not used and it is my delimeter for the output'.
- Am I being too strict on the output? The aim was that you are trying to compress it only via replacements, and as a result want to output those replacements as short as you can, which this format is the smallest you can make.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what you mean by "*The replacement rules are restricted to the same character set that the input has*", even with the explanation. 2. [A simplified version of this problem is NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem), so I'm not sure what "best algorithm" winning criterion you could use. 3. It would be good to have a test case where all optimal answers have a `tofind` which is more than one character (ensuring that answers solve the problem stated, not just that simplified version).

Comment: Seems possible if you limited to a couple replacements. Otherwise, maybe a code challenge/fastest code version?

Comment: 1. What i mean is, that the rules: `1;abcd;2;efgh` for example, must only contain characters which were allowed in the input. So you can't use weird unicode characters or things to replace
2. I'd not heard of the simplified version of this problem. In fact I think that this may be more efficient, because some rules which may be valid in that problem would not be valid due to having to factor in the additional length of the semicolons, and 3. I don't believe I have such a solution available, maybe none exist like that?

Comment: I think algorithm is a no-go from Peter's response since it does seem to be NP complete, maybe I could restrict it to be at most 3 replacements as per Michael Klein's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

## xkcd's Fast Bogosort

[This xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1185/) presents pseudocode for four very bad sorting algorithms: **halfhearted merge sort**, **fast bogosort**, **job interview quicksort**, and **panic sort**. Because the other three are too easy, impossible to decipher, or a danger to users, you'll be implementing fast bogosort.

Your code will take an array of positive integers in any convenient format, and will return or output the result of fast bogosort as defined below.

Let N be the [binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) of the length of the list, **rounded** to the nearest non-negative integer. Shuffle the list randomly N times. After each shuffle, if the list is fully sorted, return the result.

If no value has yet been returned, return the exact string `Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2)`.

The output of your code must match the expected probabilities of this algorithm exactly, but does not need to follow the explicit steps stated.

#### Test cases

In the format `Input -> Output (Probability)`

```
[] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (1)
[1] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (1)
[1, 1] -> [1, 1] (1)
[1, 2] -> [1, 2] (1/2)
[1, 2] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (1/2)
[1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 1] (1)
[1, 1, 2] -> [1, 1, 2] (5/9)
[1, 1, 2] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (4/9)
[3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3] (11/36)
[3, 2, 1] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (25/36)
[8, 4, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 4, 8] (47/576)
[8, 4, 2, 1] -> Kernel Page Fault (Error Code: 2) (529/576)
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7] -> [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7] (1)
```

#### Meta

Any bad math in here? Any other good test cases I should add?

Comment: 1. The requirement to "*match the expected probabilities of this algorithm exactly*" needs to be relaxed slightly because most systems don't have perfect RNGs. 2. If you're allowing built-in sorts, the only interesting part is rounding the logarithm. And that's really the only difference to [the bogosort question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/388/194), so it's quite likely to be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Vowel

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There is a word puzzle called *Enter Vowel* which looks a little like a crossword but the clues are simply the answers with all the vowels removed.

Your task will be to take a solved crossword and turn it back into the Enter Vowel clues. You can assume that the crossword consists of upper case letters, octothorpes and newlines. You can also assume that the crossword will be rectangular and that only octothorpes will appear on its borders.

The first step is of course to obscure the letters. Each letter should be replaced by a space, except those letters that begin a word, which should be replaced by an underline. Each underline is notionally numbered starting from 1.

To the right of the obscured grid you must then provide separate columns of across and down clues, but both sets of clues share the underline numbering, so that the numbers are not consecutive within each list of clues. The clues are simply the original words with the vowels removed.

Example:

```
###############
###PROGRAMMING#
###U####N######
###Z##CODE#####
###Z###########
#GOLF##########
###E###########
###S###########
###############
```

becomes

```
############### ACROSS      DOWN
###_    _     # 1. PRGRMMNG 1. PZZLS
### #### ###### 3. CD       2. ND
### ##_   ##### 4. GLF
### ###########
#_   ##########
### ###########
### ###########
###############
```

Extra whitespace is permissible as long as the general formatting is adhered to.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you need to remove as much code as you can.

Comment: The example given includes a full border of one line of `#`s. Can answers assume that this border will always be included?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Unless you can suggest nicer ASCII or Unicode art to represent a crossword, then yes, I think the input should always have the border.

Comment: Then please make that explicit in the question, because it simplifies the answers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I also added that it will always be rectangular, because I wasn't sure that was sufficiently obvious.

Answer (score 1):

## Untangle the footnote labyrinths

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

[image]

### Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program or function that untangles footnote labyrinths.

#### Input

The input will be made up of two parts:

- A "main" string
- A list of footnotes in the format (`1. Footnote text`)

#### Output

The output should be the "main" string with each footnote mark (represented with superscript tags `<sup>1</sup>`) replaced with its corresponding footnote. Examples:

```
This is some sample text.<sup>1</sup>
1. This is a sample footnote.
```

The "main" string has one footnote `<sup>1</sup>`; the `1` is replaced with the text of the footnote:

```
This is some sample text.<sup>This is a sample footnote.</sup>
```

Here's another one:

```
This is some sample text.<sup>1</sup>
1. This is a footnote.<sup>2</sup>
2. This is a nested footnote.
```

This time, the footnote has a footnote mark in it, which should be replaced as well:

```
This is some sample text.<sup>This is a footnote.<sup>This is a nested footnote.</sup></sup>
```

One more example:

```
Welcome to my lair!<sup>8</sup><sup><sup>3</sup></sup>
3. This footnote is not inserted.
```

Footnote 3 is inserted, but footnote 8 does not exist, so it's not modified:

```
Welcome to my lair!<sup>8</sup><sup><sup>This footnote is not inserted.</sup></sup>
```

You may assume:

- Nested footnotes are not represented as `<sup>1<sup>2</sup></sup>`; rather as `<sup>1</sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup>`.
- There will be no circular references, i.e. `1. Abc<sup>1</sup>` or `1. Abc<sup>2</sup> 2. Xyz<sup>1</sup>`
- The footnote numbers will only be 1 through 9.

You may *not* assume:

- The footnote numbers will be consecutive, or in order. `2. Abc 1. Xyz` and `9. Qwerty 4. Asdf` are both valid.

### Test cases

(One or more lines of input, empty line, output. Feel free to suggest a better format.)

```
This is some sample text.<sup>1</sup>
1. This is a sample footnote.

This is some sample text.<sup>This is a sample footnote.</sup>

_____________________________________________________________________

This is some sample text.<sup>1</sup>
1. This is a footnote.<sup>2</sup>
2. This is a nested footnote.

This is some sample text.<sup>This is a footnote.<sup>This is a nested footnote.</sup></sup>

_____________________________________________________________________

Studies have shown<sup>1</sup> that PPCG users are more likely to accept typos<sup>3</sup> than the correct spelling<sup>4<sup>5</sup></sup>.
1. Studies by an individual research group, not affiliated with PPCG in any way.
3. https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/pull/50
4. http://strawpoll.me/6847681/r
5. Very comprehensive studies.<sup>1</sup>

Studies have shown<sup>Studies by an individual research group, not affiliated with PPCG in any way.</sup> that PPCG users are more likely to accept typos<sup>https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/pull/50</sup> than the correct spelling<sup>http://strawpoll.me/6847681/r<sup>Very comprehensive studies.<sup>Studies by an individual research group, not affiliated with PPCG in any way.</sup></sup></sup>.

_____________________________________________________________________

Welcome to my lair!<sup>It's very cozy.</sup>
1. This footnote is not inserted.

Welcome to my lair!<sup>It's very cozy.</sup>

_____________________________________________________________________

Welcome to my lair!<sup>8</sup><sup><sup>3</sup></sup>
3. This footnote is not inserted.

Welcome to my lair!<sup>8</sup><sup><sup>This footnote is not inserted.</sup></sup>
```

This is code-golf, so **shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Zgarb had a challenge that was either this or the exact opposite transformation. I'll try to look it up later.

Comment: [Ah yeah, the opposite.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58013/8478)

Comment: @Martin Interesting. Would that have any bearing on this challenge being a duplicate?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

### How long until a five-card-stud poker winning hand?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

#### Background:

Five card stud is a variant of poker where the player is dealt a *hand* of five cards from a *shoe* of multiple standard 52-card decks. This hand is then used for play/scoring, following the table listed below.

{insert chart of poker hands}

We're going to play a variation of this as follows: The dealer selects five cards out of the shoe as the *Hand to Beat*. The dealer then shuffles all the remaining cards, and deals the player five cards. If the player wins, the game is over, else the player's cards are shuffled back into the shoe and the process repeats. We want to determine the expected number of hands that will need to be dealt before the player has a hand that will beat the dealer.

#### Challenge:

Given an input of the dealer's full five-card hand, and the number of decks in the original shoe, output the expected number of games before the player will have a hand that beats the dealer's.

#### Input:

- A positive integer, `0 < n < 6` representing how many decks are in the shoe.
- A numerical or string representation of the dealer's full five-card hand. You're allowed to choose the representative encoding, and the input format, but please specify that in your answer. Examples could be `3H 2C KC QH JD` for a card-value/suit combination, or assign each card a numerical value from `1` to `52` (such as `Ace of Spades = 1, Two of Spades = 2, ... King of Hearts = 52`). Your choice.

#### Output:

- A single numeric value representing the expected number of hands that need to be dealt before the player is dealt a winning hand.

#### Examples:

*to be expanded*

```
1 "2H 3C 4S 5C 7H" >
5 "22 33 45 17 8" >
```

---

#### Meta Discussion:

Related (abandoned) challenge - [Generate random 7-carded poker hand for a given hand type](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32221/42963)

Since the related challenge isn't exactly a duplicate, I don't think the below apply, but I'll link them here for discussion purposes:
[Duplicates with different restrictions or no restrictions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8281/42963)
[Is it OK to copy a question if the old one is long dead?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5022/42963)
[Can we make use of abandoned sandbox posts?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2090/42963)
[Closing old question as duplicate of a new one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1875/42963)

Answer (score 1):

## Traffic Light Simulator 2016

In this challenge, you are in charge of all of the traffic lights in a busy city.  It is your goal to move the traffic as efficiently as possible.

### Definitions:

**City**: Everything you control.  Contains a 10x10 square grid of intersections.  All adjacent intersections are connected via roads, and intersections on an edge have 1 outside connection  (2 on corners)

**Tick**: Measures time.  For the first 10,000 ticks, 10 cars will span.  The simulation ends after all cars have left the city.

**Road**:  Moves cars from one intersection to another (or an outside connection).  Roads have a length (in ticks).

**Intersection**: 12-way intersection.  Connects 4 roads together, and allows cars to move from one road to one of the other 3.  Only 1 car per direction can travel through at a time.

**Traffic Light**:  Allows/Prevents cars from crossing an intersection.  There are 12 lights (one for each direction) at each intersection.  Lights can only be green (allows traffic) or red (prevents traffic).  If a light is green, then any intersecting paths must have been red for at least 3 ticks.

**Intersecting paths**: Paths that cross or meet assuming right-side traffic.  The following graph indicates when two paths intersect given your direction and the other lanes' directions.

```
Your        Left  Right Across
Direction  |L|R|A|L|R|A|L|R|A 
------------------------------
Left       |X   X|X   X|  X X
Straight   |X   X|X X X|X    
Right      |    X|     |X
```

**Car**: Starts at a random outside connection, and travels the shortest path to another random outside connection.  After reaching its destination, adds *1.05^(TravelDuration)* to your score.

**Outside connection**:  Has a *Busyness*, and spawns cars.  The chance of an outside connection being randomly chosen is *Busyness/Sum(Busyness of every connection)*

### Your goal:

I have provided a controller that will simulate the cars and the cities.  You need to provide a function that returns a list of `[x,y,Direction]` tuples that indicates which lights you would like to toggle.  Attempting to turn a green light with intersecting green lights will turn the intersecting lights red, and turn the light green after 3 turns.

After the simulation has run, your score is the sum of all cars' scores, lowest score wins.

Comment: Did anything ever come from this? This seems like it could be a fun challenge.

Comment: No.  I'm not convinced that there are actually interesting solutions to be had, and the controller isn't trivial to write.  If you want to take this challenge, feel free :)

Answer (score 1):

## How Many Laps?

I was at my taekwondo training last night and the first thing we do when we start is a ~5 min jog around the gym to get warmed up. The problem is as follows. We run around the edge of the gym, everyone starting from wherever they like, and everyone jogs at a slightly different speed, so there is a lot of awkward passing as no one wants to have to ruin their ***flow*** by changing speed. So i started wondering, how many times will each person be overtaken?

#### The Question

Given a square of side lengths 15m, and a person starting at each corner of the square, running at speed ***n (m/s)*** how many times will each person be passed by someone else during a 5 min jog?

#### Input/Output

- Input should take the form of 4 values that represent each persons average running  speed( Assume their speed remains constant) accurate to 3 decimal places. The range of the input may be `(0,5]`. Input may be seperated by commas or spaces i.e `4.123,2.122,3.145,1.445`
- Output should be printed as 4 integers representing the number of times each person was overtaken by someone else, given in the same order as the input was supplied.

#### Test Cases

The input `1.3334 2.5334 1.1344 2.8531` can be visually represented as follows

```
1.3334 ------------ 2.5334
   |                   |
   |                   |
   |                   |
   |                   |
   |                   |
 2.8531 ------------ 1.1344
```

Each of the numbers in the corner of the square represents a jogger and their speed running in a clockwise direction(Clockwise because of the order of the input). After 5 mins of jogging, how many times will each jogger have been overtaken by everyone else?

The output for this case would be `13 1 14 0` 
This basically means the first person( top left corner) will be overtaken 13 times. The second person(top right) will be overtaken once. third person(bottom right, and the slowest jogger) will be overtaken 14 times. The fourth person( bottom left, and the fastest) will not be overtaken by anyone, as they are the fastest. Here are some more test cases

- Input: `5.3334 1.5334 1.5334 0.8531`   Output: `0 19 19 28`
- Input: `0.1334 1.5334 2.5334 3.8531`   Output: `37 16 6 0`

#### Rules

- This is code golf, shortest working program in bytes wins
- Must be a fully working program

Comment: You should really add an example, since this is very hard to imagine in your mind. Also don't forget testcases!

Comment: Haha yeah i thought someone would say that! I'm currently trying a few ideas as im not sure how to solve this myself yet! Once i have a way, ill ad some test cases

Answer (score 1):

### The broken minus parser [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Sam is trying to create a new programming language, but is having a lot of trouble getting the parser right. For example,

```
4--5
```

evaluates correctly to `4 - (-5) = 9`, but

```
4-5
```

is giving a result of `-20`!

After doing some digging around, Sam realises that their parser's grammar is ambiguous. In fact, it's actually interpreting `4-5` as `4 (-5)`, multiplication (by juxtaposition) between two numbers!

Here's some example inputs and outputs, to get a feel for what the parser's doing woeful wrong:

```
Input             Calculation                 Output
7                 7                           7
-7                (-7)                        -7
8-3               8 (-3)                      -24
8--3              8 - (-3)                    11
-8-3              (-8) (-3)                   24
-8--3             (-8) - (-3)                 -5
-4-5-2            (-4) (-5) (-2)              -40
-4--5-2           ((-4) - (-5)) (-2)          -2
-4-5--2           (-4) ((-5) - (-2))          12
-4--5--2          (-4) - (-5) - (-2)          3
1-4-5-9           1 (-4) (-5) (-9)            -180
1-4--5-9          1 ((-4) - (-5)) (-9)        -9
1--4-5--9         (1 - (-4)) ((-5) - (-9))    20
1--4--5--9        1 - (-4) - (-5) - (-9)      19
```

To be a bit more explicit, here's the rules followed by the parser, in order:

1. **Multiplication by juxtaposition**: If possible, split the input into two valid parts `a`, `b` such that `a` is as short as possible. Return `evaluate(a) * evaluate(b)`.
2. **Subtraction**: If the input is of the form `a-b` where `a`, `b` are two valid parts, return `evaluate(a) - evaluate(b)`, taking the `-` such that `b` is as short as possible.
3. **Unary negation**: If the input is of the form `-a` where `a` is valid and does not start with a `-`, return `-evaluate(a)`. In other words, unary negation can only be applied once.
4. **Digit**: If the input consists of a single digit, return the corresponding integer.

If an input string fails to satisfy any of the above conditions, it is invalid. For example, the following strings are invalid:

```
(empty)
-
7-
--7
8---3
```

### The task

Given a valid string consisting of `0123456789-`, output the result as interpreted by Sam's broken parser. Invalid input is undefined behaviour. You may assume the usual [code golf defaults](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) for input and output, e.g. programs and functions are both okay.

### Sandbox notes:

- I'll work on the algorithm description a bit later so it doesn't sound so much like "just implement this".
- Will add more test cases later.
- Should `eval`-like functions be allowed? I'm not sure how much they'd help here
- With the current rules, `42` would evaluate to `4*2=8`. Would it be preferable to state that input will never have two or more digits in a row?

Comment: Doesn't rule 1 already cause `42` to be evaluated as `4*2=8` by having precedence above rule 4?

Comment: @xnor Ah true, yes it does (updated). I'm still tossing up whether `42` should be a valid test case - I'm wondering if it might be more interesting golfing-wise if you only ever had single digits...

Comment: I think `eval`-like functions should be allowed because it disallowing doesn't add much to the challenge

Answer (score 1):

### Visualize the Euclidean Algorithm by Tiling Rectangles

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

**META: What's your opinion on moving this to a pop-con instead of a code-golf?**

---

Suppose we have two positive integers, *m* and *n*. We can use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the *greatest common divisor* of these two numbers (the largest number that divides both numbers without a remainder). This is done by essentially taking successive subtractions of remainders until you reach zero. The linked Wikipedia article goes into much greater depth, and the mathematics behind it, for the curious.

Here, though, we're going to visualize the algorithm by taking a rectangle of size *m* x *n* and recursively tiling the rectangle with successively smaller and smaller squares until all space is consumed. The length of the side of the smallest square is thus the `gcd(m,n)`.

Assuming *m* >= *n*, the first square is of size *n* x *n*, and is placed against the bottom edge. This repeats until a square does not fit, leaving a rectangle of size *n* x *(m-kn)* remaining, where *k* is how many *n* x *n* squares fit. That process then repeats on the newly-formed rectangle, starting on the left side, then the bottom, then the left, etc., until the original *m* x *n* rectangle is fully tiled.

Here's a beautifully done animated example, from that Wikipedia page, of 1071 and 462, showing the result to be 21.
<sub>By Proteins (Own work) [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), via Wikimedia Commons.</sub>

[image]

#### Input

- Two distinct positive integers, *m* and *n*, via any convenient input method. Without loss of generality, you can assume *m* > *n* (for example, if you take input as a tuple, your program can assume that the first element is always the larger of the two, and you don't need to test size).
- Your implementation should be able to handle input up to your language's default `int` size (or equivalent).

#### Output

- An image of at least 300px square, but no bigger than 1200px square, showing a rectangle of proportion *m* x *n*, tiled with successively smaller squares as described above. This means that for small inputs the rectangle will need to be stretched, and for large inputs the rectangle will need to be shrunk.
- The image must be oriented so that *m* (the larger) is the vertical dimension and *n* is the horizontal.
- Squares of the same size must be distinct. This could be done by coloring the squares differently from their neighbors, by enclosing each square in a border (as in the above animation), etc.
- Output does not necessarily need to be in color, so long as the squares are distinct and understandable.
- The image can be displayed on-screen or saved to a file.

#### Examples

*[TODO]*

Answer (score 1):

## Transpose a paragraph

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

For some odd reason I want to transpose paragraphs. The basic idea of a transpose is that this:

```
a b
c d
```

Is changed to:

```
a c
b d
```

[more on the rules here]

### Examples

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer suscipit, arcu
ut facilisis blandit, neque tellus consequat urna, in semper mi purus vel magna.
Nam placerat mauris ac varius dictum. Nunc placerat ipsum et lectus iaculis
feugiat. Aenean eget felis ac purus fermentum dapibus ac nec leo. Vestibulum
convallis euismod metus a gravida. In eu nisl facilisis, accumsan urna a,
consectetur mauris. Integer vitae lectus et justo vestibulum lobortis. Donec
quis erat est. Curabitur pellentesque mi purus, vel posuere nunc volutpat quis.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
Curae; Maecenas ultrices, elit sed finibus euismod, lacus tortor hendrerit
libero, quis auctor risus mi in tortor. Vivamus finibus consectetur est, quis
ultricies metus congue sit amet. Ut non elit libero. Fusce efficitur nec ante ut
tempor. Proin vitae commodo tortor. In aliquam massa a nulla eleifend commodo. 

Lorem      ut         Nam        feugiat.   convallis  consectetu quis       Vestibulum Curae;     libero,    ultricies  tempor.   
ipsum      facilisis  placerat   Aenean     euismod    mauris.    erat       ante       Maecenas   quis       metus      Proin     
dolor      blandit,   mauris     eget       metus      Integer    est.       ipsum      ultrices,  auctor     congue     vitae     
sit        neque      ac         felis      a          vitae      Curabitur  primis     elit       risus      sit        commodo   
amet,      tellus     varius     ac         gravida.   lectus     pellentesq in         sed        mi         amet.      tortor.   
consectetu consequat  dictum.    purus      In         et         mi         faucibus   finibus    in         Ut         In        
adipiscing urna,      Nunc       fermentum  eu         justo      purus,     orci       euismod,   tortor.    non        aliquam   
elit.      in         placerat   dapibus    nisl       vestibulum vel        luctus     lacus      Vivamus    elit       massa     
Integer    semper     ipsum      ac         facilisis, lobortis.  posuere    et         tortor     finibus    libero.    a         
suscipit,  mi         et         nec        accumsan   Donec      nunc       ultrices   hendrerit  consectetu Fusce      nulla     
arcu       purus      lectus     leo.       urna       volutpat   posuere    est,       efficitur  eleifend  
vel        iaculis    Vestibulum a,         quis.      cubilia    quis       nec        commodo.
```

Comment: Where did "vel" (at the bottom of column 1 in your output) come from?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I don't (and won't) have time to fix it for a while. 1-2 months min.

Answer (score 1):

## What can I buy in Catan?

[Catan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catan) is a board game where players collect 5 commodities: **b**rick, **l**umber, **w**ool, **g**rain and **o**re.

You can trade commodities in the following ways:

- you can always sell 4 of one kind to buy 1 of any other kind
- if you have 3-for-1 trading possibility you can sell 3 of one kind to buy 1 of any other kind
- if you have a given commodity trading possibility you can sell 2 of the given commodity to buy 1 of any other kind

You can use your commodities to buy 4 things:

- **r**oad costs 1 brick and 1 lumber
- **s**ettlement costs 1 brick, 1 lumber, 1 wool and 1 grain
- **c**ity costs 2 grain and 3 ore
- **d**evelopment card costs 1 wool, 1 grain and 1 ore

The same costs in matrix form:

```
 |blwgo
-+-----
r|11
s|1111
c|   23
d|  111
```

Your task is to find out which of the four things a player could buy given his/her commodities and trading possibilities.

### Input

### Output

### Examples

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Sort My Youtube Playlist

Help! My playlist is all unsorted! I need to sort it, but I can only move a video to the top or the bottom. I'd like to do this quickly so I need a solution with the minimum amount of moves. But I'm lazy and it seemed like a good fit, so I'm posting it here and now you have to do it! Now, since this is code golf, you have to do it in as few bytes as possible.

Input is a permutation of the values from 1 to n (where n is any number from 1 to ∞). Output is a list of moves that sorts the list.
For example for input `1 3 2 4` a valid output would be `2D 3D` (second element to bottom, third element to bottom)

Test cases:

```
Input         Possible Output
1 3 2 4       2D 3D
5 4 3 2 1     4D 3D 2D 1D
```

Comment: I'd flag as unclear. Input and output specifications? Test cases? Just a description is not enough.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the test cases. No matter which side I try as "bottom", neither one of the outputs seem to sort the inputs.

Comment: For the first input, it is `1 3 2 4` `1 2 4 3` `1 2 3 4` For the second, `5 4 3 2 1` `5 4 3 1 2` `4 5 3 1 2` `4 5 1 2 3` `5 1 2 3 4` `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: 1. "*A list of values from 1 to n*" without any other mention of n says nothing about whether or not there are duplicates. I think you mean "*a permutation of the integers from `1` to `n`*", but that needs to be explicit. 2. The top appears to be index 0 (or 1 in weird languages) and the bottom index n-1, but that needs to be explicit. 3. `2D` seems to mean "move the value at *index* 2 to the bottom": "*element 2*" is far too easy to interpret as the element with *value* 2. 4. The first paragraph says "*minimum amount of moves*", but the second test case doesn't meet that criterion.

Answer (score 1):

## Recompose a series of alternating binary sequences

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**This is the inverse of [Decompose binary into alternating subsequences](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8666/12914).** The essence of this linked challenge is to convert a decimal integer to binary, split on adjacent 0s or 1s (like `010110001` would become `0101 10 0 01`), and convert each subsequence back to decimal.

Let's take a sequence of positive integers in decimal, like

```
10 21 2 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 5 1 85 5 1 1 1 5 1 1
```

And convert each number to binary...

```
1010 10101 10 101 1 1 1 1 1 10 1 10 101 1 1010101 101 1 1 1 101 1 1
```

But wait, this is the *inverse* of the decomposition problem. The original binary representation was split where there were two adjacent 0s or 1s. Hence, if `10101` comes after `1010`, then there must have been a leading 0. Adding these in results in this:

```
1010 010101 10 0101 1 1 1 1 1 10 01 10 0101 1 1010101 101 1 1 1 101 1 1
```

Which, after concatenation and converting back to decimal, gives `727429805944311` as the final answer.

### The Task

Take a sequence of positive integers as input and output a single positive integer after recomposition.

### The Details

- Input may be in a sensible, human-readable format that is convenient for your language. All integers must be in decimal or unary, and no precomputation in the input is allowed.
- Output must be a single positive integer, in either decimal or unary.

### Test Cases

```
Input                Output
0                    0
1                    1
2                    2
1 1                  3
2 0                  4
5                    5
1 2                  6
1 1 1                7
2 0 0                8
2 1                  9
10                   10
1 2 2                50
1 2 2 0              100
1 1 1 1 10 0 0       1000
2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0    10000
1 2 2 1 1 2 2        12914
5 42 10 2 1          371017
```

Comment: "Easily" is a bit (read: very) subjective. Does retina count? Sed? I'd recommend just allowing unary, the problem doesn't seem like it would be easily solved in unary, so it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: Good point. I'll edit both questions to say that.

Comment: Can you edit this so it is comprehensible without reading another question? E.g.: "The original binary representation was split where there were two adjacent 0s or 1s." -- says who?

Comment: @msh210: How is it now?

Comment: … Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Count the Esolang Puns

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) | [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) | [counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

This challenge was inspired by [this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/language-puns) in chat.

### Introduction

Yesterday in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte),
there was a conversation where several people extensively used esolang puns. @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ kept a tally throughout to see who used the most puns. Your job will be to help him out by counting the puns.

### Challenge

Your challenge will take several strings as input and output a list of scores. Input can be in a list, separated by newlines, etc. Output can be in any convenient format, in any order. Each string of input will be in the form `user : message`. Both `user` and `message` will only contain printable ASCII characters. You need to count the amount of language puns used in the message and add it to that user's tally. Use [this list](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) as the list of languages that count as "pun" languages. You may not read this list from external sources (webpage, file, etc.). In the case of a overlap of languages (ex. `example` contains the languages `example` and `exam`), count all of them (so the example would contain 2 languages). Language names are case insensitive while counting (`retina` and `ReTinA` are the same).

#### Example IO

Input (taken from the actual conversation):

```
AlexA. : @Mego He may be CJamming things
ConorO'Brien : I'm jelly >:I
GamrCorps : @AlexA. Argh! The Aura from the eclipse burned by Retinas. Good thing it didn't deal too much damage or I would RAGE!!!
ConorO'Brien : The hexagony, I'm losing.
```

Output:

```
[["AlexA.", 1], ["Conor'OBrien", 2], ["GamrCorps", 4]]
```

***Meta Note: Ill add more IO when I get back in an hour or so.***

Comment: So, its basically counting the instances of a substring?

Comment: @NathanMerrill yes, counting the instances of several substrings, and outputting the total amount *per person*

Comment: "You may hardcode that list in your program or read that webpage." Unless you're planning on deducting the hard-coded list from the score or similar, this gives an unfair advantage to languages that can read the webpage.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming we should match the language names case-insensitively.

Comment: @AquaTart Yes it should be case insensitive, I updated the post along with removing the ability to read from the web.

Comment: Isn't most of this challenge compressing the list of languages?

Answer (score 1):

## ACSII Cell Game

The ASCII Cell Game is a simple game where the player has a grid (5x10) of cells (`| |`):

```
_____________________
| | | |X| | | | | | |
---------------------
| | | | | | | | | | |
---------------------
| | | | | | | |X| | |
---------------------
| | | |X| | | | | | |
---------------------
| | | | | | | |X| | |
---------------------
```

Any cells marked with an `X` have died, and any cells with an `O` have been blocked. The object of the game is for the spread of `X`'s to stop. The player inputs a point i.e. `1,5` and the computer places an `O` there. The `X`s spread to all adjacent cells every 2 seconds.

---

### Game Rules:

1. This  is traditional code golf with the shortest in bytes winning. I will test this on my computer.

Comment: The specification is not clear. Specify exactly what should happen to display the game board (does it need to update every iteration, or even display at all?); when the game ends (when every square is blocked?); whether players should be prevented from moving in an `O` or `X` square, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## How fast can I Flood-It?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

There's a one-player game called [Flood-It](http://unixpapa.com/floodit/), in which the player must flood the whole board with one color within a certain number of moves.

- The board is a two-dimensional square grid of size ***n***.
- At the start, each square in the grid is one of ***k*** colors.
- A move consists of selecting a color, and doing a 4-connected flood fill with that color starting in the top left corner.

For example, selecting `R`ed on this size-3 board with 4 colors:

```
GGE
RGB
RDE
```

causes the board to change to this—now the two already-red squares are connected to the top left:

```
RRE
RRB
RDE
```

After the further moves `DBE`, all squares are colored `E`merald, and the game has been won in an optimal 4 moves.

### Challenge

Given two integers ***n*** and ***k***, output the number of moves required to win the game of Flood-It with those parameters, in the worst case over all possible arrangements of colors.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125517/194).

Answer (score 1):

## Infinite [Hexagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony) Loops

In this challenge, we will be determining whether or not a restricted-source hexagony program terminates or loops forever.

**Input**

A hexagony program that contains only the

- "Flow Control" characters: **/ | _ | > <**
- the no-op character: **.**
- the program terminate character: **@**

Note that since every memory edge is zero for the duration of every program, **there are no conditionals** in this restricted source version of the language.

- The side length of the hexagon may be any natural number.
- You may assume that inputs are padded with no-op characters to fit the hexagon shape exactly (or you may strip all trailing no-ops as long as you do not change the hexagon size)
- You may take the input in any reasonable fashion.
- *DESCRIPTIONS OF WHAT EACH OF THE FLOW CONTROL CHARACTERS DO WILL BE COMING SOON. IN THE MEANTIME, LOOK AT THE [WIKI PAGE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony)*

**Output**

A truthy value if the program terminates. A falsy value otherwise.

A program "terminates" if the instruction pointer reaches a '@' character.

**Test cases**

Coming soon.

**Scoring**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I approve. Especially if there is a hexagony solution

Answer (score 1):

## Zipdeck!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

A few years ago I invented a simple card game named "Zip Deck".  It's not that much fun for humans, but should be perfect for bots.  This contest will be run in Python 3.

### Zip Deck rules:

There are N players, and a deck with N*4 cards, numbered 0 to N*4-1.  The deck is shuffled (Python's `random.shuffle` function) and each player is dealt a card.  Everyone looks at their card, then, on the count of three, if you believe you have the highest card, say (return) "Zip Deck!"

If you *do* have the highest card and you said "Zip Deck", you win!  You assign floor[C/4] points, divided between the other players any way you'd like, where C is the value of your card.

If either you said "Zip Deck" but *don't* have the high card, or you do have the high card but *didn't* say "Zip Deck", you take a penalty of floor[C/4] points (min 1).

The winner is the player with the fewest total points after a set number of rounds (as of now, N<sup>2</sup> rounds, but that's subject to change if there are many, many entrants).

### What You Do:

Write a bot!  A bot is a descendant of the `Player` class.  Your bot should have a function `play` that takes two parameters, `card` (the card you're dealt) and `info` (a dictionary with information about the state of the game).  If your bot thinks it has the highest card, it should return an array containing the string "Zip Deck!" and a dictionary showing how it would assign points if it's correct.  If you don't assign enough points, your bot will take the remainder; if you assign too many, instead all of the points will be given to your bot that round.

The `info` dictionary contains the following keys:

- `'round'`: The current round, starting with zero.  Maybe your bot wants to get more reckless when the game's about to end?
- `'scores'`: A dictionary containing every player's current score.
- `'last'`: A dictionary showing what everyone was dealt last round and what the bot returned (so an array with either an empty string or "Zip Deck!" plus their point allocation).  Useful if you're trying to determine the other players' strategy.

An example `info` from one of my test runs:

```
{'scores': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 1}, 
'last': {0: [12, ['']], 1: [10, ['Zip Deck!', {2: 2}]], 2: [15, ['Zip Deck!', {1: 3}]], 3: [3, ['Zip Deck!', {1: 0}]]}, 
'round': 3}
```

Every `Player` also has two attributes that you can access, `my_num` (that player's number) and `player_count` (the total number of players).  I've imported `random` already (naturally); if you want to use any other standard library, just let me know.

```
class YourBotHere(Player):
    def __init__(self, my_num, player_count):
        super(YourBotHere, self).__init__(my_num, player_count)
    def play(self, card, info):
        # Define your own play function for your class.

        # If you think you're highest, return an array where the first element is the
        # phrase "Zip Deck!", and the second is a dictionary for how you'd assign points
        # if you win.
        # E.g. ["Zip Deck!", {0: 2, 1: 2, 4: 1}]

        # If you don't think you're highest, return an array with one element, the empty
        # string (or anything that's not "Zip Deck!")

        return [""]

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, my_num, player_count):
        self.my_num = my_num
        self.player_count = player_count
```

#### Example bots:

```
class Rando(Player):
    def __init__(self, my_num, player_count):
        super(Rando, self).__init__(my_num, player_count)
    def play(self, card, info):
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            target = {i for i in range(self.player_count)} - {self.my_num}
            target = random.choice(tuple(target))
            points = card//4
            return ["Zip Deck!", {target: points}]
        else:
            return [""]

class Serpentine(Player):
    # Zigs and zags, trying not to do the same thing too many times in a row.
    def __init__(self, my_num, player_count):
        super(Serpentine, self).__init__(my_num, player_count)
        self.two_back = True
        self.one_back = False
        self.targets = {i for i in range(self.player_count)} - {self.my_num}
    def play(self, card, info):
        if len(self.targets) == 0:
            self.targets = {i for i in range(self.player_count)} - {self.my_num}
        will_call = False
        if self.two_back == self.one_back:
            will_call = not self.two_back
        elif card/(self.player_count*4) > 0.8:
            will_call = True

        self.two_back = self.one_back
        self.one_back = will_call

        if will_call:
            target = self.targets.pop()
            return ["Zip Deck!", {target: card//4}]
        else:
            return [""]
```

### Controller

The controller code can be found on [my GitHub](https://github.com/madjaqk/zipdeck) (along with most of these instructions again verbatim).  [You can also see OrionBot, the one entry I got when I tried to run this competition in class; I'll remove it so that only PPCG bots are in the tournament before this goes live.]  Intentionally bad or losing strategies are OK, but bots that attempt to crash the controller/cause an infinite loop will be disallowed, as are bots that collude or cooperate in any way.

### Sandbox Concerns

First and most importantly, does everything in the rules write-up make sense?  Are there any loopholes I haven't considered?

This game is straightforward enough that the winning strategy might be completely boring, but I don't think it's necessarily obvious that it will be.  Also, I would have said that rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock has a very clear and well-known best strategy in game-theoretic terms, and [that challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35079/the-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-tournament-of-epicness) still saw a dizzying array of answers.

Comment: Hello, welcome to PPCG, and thanks for using the Sandbox! :) From what I can see, this looks alright, but I'd definitely leave it around a while to see what people think. I'd be concerned that the best strategy for calling "Zip Deck" might be random, in particular. Also, this game seems relatively simple, so if you feel like you could probably create a controller that passed the values as strings and allowed more than just python answers. Some other challenges have done that to great success e.g. [Good Versus Evil](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33137/31625)

Comment: Thank you!  I'd love to open this up to more than just Python answers, but I haven't worked with the Subprocess.  I'll have to spend some time with it to see if I can make it work.

Comment: 1. As far as I can see, the rules don't actually state what values are on the cards. That's quite an important detail. 2. IMO you should restrict to no more than one entry per user and no cooperation between users.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good catch!  I've updated accordingly.  (The cards are valued from 0 to N*4-1)  I feel like most King of the Hill challenges I've looked at allow players to submit multiple bots, though; has there been a problem with that in the past, beyond the obvious [Soviet chess player issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1963#Allegations_of_collusion)?

Comment: I've got a nice [Communicator class in python](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/ScoreboardKoTH/blob/master/Communicator.py).  That said, I've actually moved away from Python for KoTHs because its slow, so its been a while since I used it, but it should be fairly unbuggy.

Comment: Also, the reason that RPSLS got so many answers is because it was simple and had a pop-culture reference.  Its hard making a spec that is simple and easy to read (I'm a terrible example, IMO), and unfortunately, I don't see any pop-cultureness in this challenge.  That said, best of luck to your challenge!

Comment: There has been intentional submission of entries which were intended to collude to the benefit of other entries in the past; my proposal is more extreme than any which has been implemented so far, but there have been other KotHs which explicitly prohibited collusion. I'm concerned that with this format where you can choose to whom you want to assign points if you win there is a greater than usual benefit to collusion.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1332/31541), but also different. I need help phrasing things, putting them together coherently, etc.

Also, I can't decide on what the magic numbers (size, toggles per turn, etc.) should be.

Lastly, is this even winnable?

(oh, and if anyone wants to write a nice "backstory", that'd be much appreciated)

(also I have a couple of notes to myself in there so I remember what I was doing when I come back to this later)

---

---

### Murderous Life

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata) [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

#### Overview

The game is played on a 100-cell-wide, 300-cell-long board. It's cylinder-shaped -- patterns will wrap around the long sides, but not the short ones. Attempts to toggle cells behind the short edges will fail, and all cells along the short edge are considered dead. The center 200x100 area (the "no man's land") is the focus of the game. The farthest left 50x100 area (next to the origin) is the Police Headquarters, and is where the police can send units from. The far right is the Robber Hideout, and is where they operate from.

Your program will communicate with the controller via standard input and output. Each message is terminated with a newline (`\n`, ASCII code 10). The code your program *must* exit when it receives Control+C (ASCII code 3). It doesn't have to stop immediately -- for example, if you have to close IO handles -- but it should take less than a second. It also doesn't have to end cleanly -- throwing an error is fine. As long as you've tidied up after yourself.

Immediately, both programs print to STDOUT their name and their author's name, with a hyphen in between, followed by a newline. This signals that they are ready to begin receiving input. After that, the turns will start immediately. The turns work like this:

1. Both players are sent a string containing the current map through their STDIN. The format is detailed below.
2. The desired moves are collected from each program in no particular order.

   - > Note: If the moves are invalid for any reason -- they attempt to change a blocked square, too long, fail to precisely match the format, anything like that -- then the program is immediately ejected from the game, and I'll drop a comment on your post letting you know what happened.
3. All of the moves are applied at once to the board
4. One iteration of Conway's Game of Life (standard rules) is run on the map.
5. The number of living cells in the No Man's Land is tallied.

The game runs for 5000 turns, after which the average number of living squares in the No Man's Land is calculated. This is the score of both the cop and the robber. Once three answers of each type have been submitted -- aside from the example ones -- I'll begin playing the answers against each other. The scoreboard will be updated daily until at least a week after the first answers have been submitted, or if it's later, three days after the last one has. The full score of any given program is the average of all of its scores.

Each program will be played against every other exactly once. Any attempts to communicate or disrupt the other AI -- except through the board -- are banned. If your bot doesn't respond to CTRL+D or CTRL+C, it will be banned.

Note that, if you have to do some cleanup before exiting, that's fine -- the "kill switches" don't have to work instantly. They do, however, have to work quickly. They can throw an error or something like that if you like.

You can always assume you'll get valid input.

#### In Cops version:

The point of the game, for the cops, is to keep the board as dead as possible. You can toggle up to 30 cells in the Police Headquarters per turn, creating or removing whatever patterns you like. At the end of the game, the Cop program with the lowest score wins.

#### In Robbers version:

The point of the game, for the robbers, is to make as many cells in the No Man's Land alive as possible. You can toggle up to 20 cells in the Robber Hideout per turn, in whatever arrangement you want. At the end of the game, the Robber program with the highest score wins.

[link to the opposite side's version]

---

#### Message format

Aside from the initial name string, all messages passed between programs will be like this:

```
1,4 12,0 9,125 299,6
```

Each pair is a coordinate pair, with the X values first and Y values second. The origin is at the top left of the board -- on the Police side of the board. The indexes are zero-based.

To be explicitly clear, the format is a space-delimited string of pairs. Each pair consists of two base-ten numbers, between 1 and 3 digits long, separated by a comma. The first number must not have a value greater than 299 or less than 0, and the second number must not have a value greater than 99 or less than 0. In addition, the first number must be between 0 and 49 (inclusive) if the player is a Cop, or between 250 and 299 (inclusive) if the player is a Robber.

---

I've written a basic example bot. To change what side it's on, simple change the comments on the lines indicated.

```
# Uncomment the part marked with the team this one should be on
#Cops
place_at = (0..47).to_a.product (0..97).to_a
glider = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
toggles = 30
#Robbers
place_at = (0..47).to_a.product (0..97).to_a
glider = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [0, 2]]
toggles = 20

puts 'GliderLover-QPaysTaxes'

while gets
  # We don't care what the board is like in this dumb AI.
  puts toggles.times.map {
    loc = place_at.sample
    glider.map { |offset| loc.zip(offset).map { |(a, b)| a+b }.join ',' }.join ' '
  }.join ' '
end
```

---

---

Is there anything else I need to specify?

Comment: .. I think this is the first C&R with a controller we've had?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Maybe! It fits CaR better than KOTH, though.

Comment: @QPaysUnicornTaxes yeah.

Comment: I think tagging this as KOTH is logical. The closest thing done before was: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51029/31203. Maybe putting both tags would be ideal.

Comment: @MegaTom Hm, probably. It's certainly got elements of both. I still haven't finished the controller though, so until then I can't post anything :)

Answer (score 1):

### [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) A Simple Card Game

Take 2 standard decks of cards, and 4 players. Shuffle the deck, and distribute the cards evenly among the 4 players. Each player will take **one** card in their hand (visible to only the player himself), and place the others on a stack in front of them.

**Overview:**
The goal is to collect **all** the cards. Taking turns, each player will play a card from either their hand, or hope for the best and play the **first** card from their stack. After all players have taken turns, the player with the highest card* will win that round and will collect the played cards. He will then **start the next round**.

**Replenishing / losing / winning**
If you play a card from your hand, you may draw the first card from your stack and place it in your hand. If you run out of cards on your stack, you may shuffle the cards you collected, and this will be your new stack. You will be removed from the game the moment you have played the last card (which is by definition from your hand) and do not win the consequent round. Last player standing wins the game.

***Highest card**
The highest card is in principle determined by the standard sequence `2<3...<King`. **However**, when someone plays an ace, the sequence becomes `4<...<Ace<2<3`, i.e., `3` becomes the highest card. The winner is determined at the end of the round - the order of play is irrelevant.

**If there's a tie**, the 'winning' players do another round, and the final winning player will collect all the cards 'on the table', i.e., of all the tied rounds. *Edge case: if you tie with your final card, you will lose after all, since you have no cards to play with after the tie.*

**Examples:**
We have four players: Alice, Bob, Carol and Dave. Let's denote the cards by `[1-12]` where 1 is an ace.

```
A:  5, B: 9, C: 1, D: 8.   Winner: Carol.
C: 10  D: 4  A: 1, B: 2.   Winner: Bob (2 beats ace)
B: 11, C: 1, D: 4, A: 1.   Tie between Carol and Alice... (both aces)
C:  4, A: 3                Winner: Carol (she gets six cards).
C:  3, D: 2, A: 1, B: 6.   Winner: Carol (3 beats ace)
```

### The challenge

Build a player that will win as many games as possible. You will receive 10 points for first place, 5 for second, 3 for third and 1 for last place. Your final score will be divided by the number of simulation runs I did, so you will score `[1-10]`.

Your code must fit within [an amount of bytes to be determined; 1kiB?]

### Sandbox questions:

1. Would you consider participating? Why (not)? (challenge quality)
2. What would be better?

   - A Java controller (each player extends the default Player class). Advantage: no I/O parsing required, just simple function calls. Disadvantage: excludes all other languages, lest a wrapper is made.
   - A STDIN/STDOUT controller (each player will receive input over STDIN, and return what they do on STDOUT). Advantage: virtually any language can compete. Disadvantage: possibly cumbersome I/O format to present the players with all relevant information.

Comment: 1. Why use standard decks of cards? The mechanic would be identical if the deck has 8 copies each of the numbers 0 to 12, and the special-cased parsing would be eliminated. 2. The weird stuff with the ace isn't adequately explained. E.g. what happens if the four players play, in order, 3, A, 3, A?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the feedback! 1) I did that to make it less abstract. Eventually, I will use 1-12 for coding the cards. 2) Is it better explained now? (in your case, the two players playing a '3' would tie and have another round)

Comment: Still not very clear, no. `King < Ace` when no-one plays an ace (and therefore it doesn't matter) and `Ace < 2` when someone plays an ace, so that ***for all practical purposes*** `Ace < 2` always?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh wait, I see where the confusion comes from, my bad. Yes, you are right, and the latest edit should reflect that. Any comments on whether to use a Java controller or a STDIN/STDOUT one?

Comment: A Java controller can easily wrap a stdin/stdout one. You should be able to steal a wrapper from some existing koth. I'm still not entirely clear what's going on with the ace: is the full post-ace-play order `4<5<6<7<8<9<10<J<Q<K<A<2<3` ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, exactly. I will try to make a wrapper then, thanks once again for the feedback.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, it seems like you will never have more than one card in your hand, but the language you use implies that you can. Can you have more than one? If so, how?

Comment: You mean `the moment you have played the last card from your hand and do not win the consequent round`? I meant to say "The moment you have played the last card (which will by definition be your hand card), ...", I'll fix that phrasing. Or is any other part of the spec also confusing?

Comment: Also, you refer to playing "a" card from your hand, which makes it sound like a choice. I would replace "a" with "the" in those cases. The only thing besides that that you could add is how you will determine a winner if you have, for example, `N` bots submitted, given that the game takes exactly 4 players.

Answer (score 1):

## Compute the size of a binary tree iteratively

## Introduction

Binary trees are easy to manipulate using recursion. For example, here is Java code that declares a binary tree and determines its size (the number of nodes it contains) recursively:

```
public class BinaryTree
{
  private Node root;

  /**
   * Constructs a search tree with the given root.
   *
   * @param the root node
   */
  public BinaryTree(Node root)
  {
    this.root = root;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the number of nodes in this tree.
   */
  public int size()
  {
    return size(root);
  }

  // private helper function
  private int size(Node node)
  {
    if (node == null)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1 + size(node.getLeftChild()) + size(node.getRightChild());
  }
```

The definition of `Node` is not shown. As you would expect, it has methods `getLeftChild()` and `getRightChild()` that either return other instances of `Node` or `null`. A `Node` does not have backlinks to its parent.

## Challenge

Write a non-recursive function to determine the number of nodes in a binary tree. You should not make any assumptions about the ordering of the nodes; however, you can assume that a reasonable hash function exists on nodes such that you can expect O(1) access time using a hash table.

In addition to not calling itself, your function should not simulate recursion through a stack-like data structure, and it should not call any recursive functions. You may use standard data structures, such as a set that uses hash codes to determine membership.

Solutions will be judged by their efficiency. Specifically, they will be judged by their time complexity, with space complexity used as a tie-breaker.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG and thanks for using the Sandbox! :) [tag:fastest-algorithm] challenges are hard to run because they are hard to score well, just as an FYI. Also probably worth noting is that not all languages will have the same definition of binary tree. In addition, I'm not certain this is possible without "simulating recursion", arguably, any looping construct at all is also solvable through recursion, so I don't think that's really a good way to word this restriction.

Comment: I think that by the standards of this site, this question should be considered a dupe of [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/478/194) and therefore closed. (This is sad, because the older question is still semi-vandalised by its OP).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll be back with a different question some time.

Answer (score 1):

### Decimal to Troll

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Discworld Trolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Discworld)) have a unique number system. From Wikipedia:

> Trolls have a numeral system of their own, based on powers of 4.
>
> The base numerals are one (1), two (2), three (3), many (4) and lots (16), which can be combined to form higher numbers.
>
> When combined, each numeral's value is added to those of the others. Higher-valued numerals take priority over lower-valued ones, so that 4 is written "many" and not "two-two" or "three-one" and 20 is written "lots many" rather than "many many many many many". If there are no ones, twos or threes, the number is written with spaces between the numerals; if any exist a hyphen replaces the space between every numeral.

### The Challenge

The challenge is to write a program that accepts a positive integer and outputs the equivalent troll counting string, including the correct separator (hyphen or space) based on the above rules.

Examples (including those from Wikipedia):

```
Input   Output
-----   ------
   1      one
   2      two
   3      three
   4      many
   5      many-one
  10      many-many-two
  20      lots many
  32      lots lots
 126      lots-lots-lots-lots-lots-lots-lots-many-many-many-two
```

This is code-golf, shortest answer wins.

Comment: Nice challenge!

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe of [this challenge about money](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70847/31625). I think the greedy algorithm still works, the only differences that I see between these is the I/O formats and the amounts to use, which I'm afraid don't sufficiently differentiate them, in my opinion.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I can see the similarities, and yes, the repeating units in the output and separator are the main differences. But Discworld! :)  Happy to withdraw it if consensus is it's too similar.

Answer (score 1):

## [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) Tron Bot Racing

It's time to begin annual Tron Racing Tournament. Create a bot that will steer your cycle to a victory!

#### Glossary

*Board* is a 100x100 square that wraps around its edges.

#### Game

*Bots* leave impassable trail. In the beginning of the game, all the bots participating (2 in case of a duel) are placed randomly thorough the map. Then, at the beginning of each turn, all bots must decide the direction they will chose next (Up, Down, Right, Left) based (or not) on the available data, which is the empty cells in each of the directions. If bot tries to move into an occupied cell, his turn is repeated until it makes a valid move. If after 10 tries bot still won't make a valid move, it dies. Game ends when all bots die. Score is the length of your trail.

Example:

```
. . . . . d . .
. . . b b b b .     Received data:
. . . b . u b .     L0 U3 R3 D3 T1
. . . b . u b .     
. . . b . u b .     Length of line of sight is `ceil(map_size/2) - 1`
r . . b b B r r     and it wraps around map edges.  
. . . . . d . .     u, r, d - lines of sight
. . . . . d . .     B - bot, b - bot's trail
```

If bot decides to go Left (and will collide with his own trail), he is invoked one more time with Tries increased: `L0 U3 R3 D3 T2'.

#### Submissions

The engine is written in Node.js, so your bot should be a function in Javascript that accepts 1 argument (state array) and returns integer between 0 - 3 which corresponds to your chosen direction.

```
function RandomBot(state) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
```

0 - Left, 1 - Up, 2 - Right, 3 - Down

You can also write your bot in any other runnable language. It will be run every time a decision needs to be made, with data pushed into StdIn `3,3,0,2,1` and output (single integer) required at StdOut.

However, by using Javascript you have the advantage to use *this* to save data between runs.

#### Winner and conditions

Bots will be dueling with each other, each duel repeated 100 times. Standard loopholes apply.

## Meta

How to create leaderboard? How to score wins and loses?
Is there anything that can be improved? This is my first entry ever and I have already a working prototype. I have concerns with the data passed to bots. Maybe its too small? Anyway, let me know what do you think about it guys.

Comment: [Similar](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5388/194)

Comment: [Even more similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26293/14215). Except for limited data/sight, it's a duplicate.

Comment: I think that if the match would consist of bigger board and all the bots at once, it would be different enough to not be a duplicate.

Comment: I agree that a free-for-all should be sufficiently different, especially given the limited sight. Then again, with that many walls floating around, it could end up being very hard to avoid an impossible trap. You might want to do some test runs with some naive bots to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

## [Chopsticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopsticks_(hand_game))

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Overview (basically the wiki page)

Chopsticks is a game played with two hands and two people. Both start with one finger out on each hand, the finger count. On a player's turn, they must choose one of their opponent's hands. That opponent adds the player's finger count to the one on that hand (and extends that many fingers). Once a hand's finger count has reached five or more, that hand's finger count is reduced to 0 and can't be used. Once both hands are out, the opponent wins.

To make the game more interesting, there is a mechanic called splitting: A player may use his turn to divide both his hand counts **differently** than he/she already has. A valid move would be to split from a 2 and a 3 to a 4 and a 1. An invalid move would be to split from a 2 and a 3 to a 3 and a 2. It is illegal to bring a hand back to life like a bunch of my friends like to do, as in split from a 4 and a 0 (a hand that is out) to a 2 and a 2 (back in). I deem it legal (since the Wikipedia article didn't say anything about it) to get one of your hands out using splitting, such as going from 3 and 4 to 2 and 5 (out).

## Challenge

Your task is to write a bot that will play chopsticks against another bot.

## Input

Every time your bot takes a turn, it will be given its opponent's finger count and its own finger count in this format:

```
[opponent hand 1] [opponent hand 2] [own hand 1] [own hand 2]
```

There will be spaces in between each value as shown above. Each value will be an integer. The bot should remember the hand numbers, as it is important to the output.

## Output

Your bot must take the data, decide what to do with it, and respond accordingly. Output is in this form:

```
[target hand] [attacking hand]
```

where `[target]` refers to the target opponent's hand and `[hand]` refers to the hand you are hitting the target with. A valid output would be `1, 2`, which says that the bot wants to hit the opponent's first hand with its own second hand.

## Problems and todo (sandbox)

- I do not yet know how to make a program that handles all of this. I'll try to work on it.
- There will be a bracket.
- Should I make tweaks to the game to make it more suitable?
- I may or may not follow through, but regardless I would like feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is an alternating turn game with about 6125 states. It's therefore very likely that every submission will play perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> You have an even number of identical balls. Half of them are "Light" balls and other half are "Heavy" balls which are heavier than the light balls for a unknown amount. You have to separate them into the "Light" box and a "Heavy" box using a scale instrument which tells you precisely for how much the left side is heavier than the right side when the balls are weighted on it.
>   
>   Find a way to separate a given number of the balls with the minimal weightings as possible.

This is a challenge to programmatically reslove [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762437/separating-heavier-from-the-lighter-balls).

---

**The solution** should be an algorithm  that would separate the given amount of balls with the least weightings  as possible.

The **Input** can be any even number of balls, where the heavy balls will differ in weight from the light balls by a random amount. The balls are marked from 1 to n, and the "heavy" and "light" properties are assigned to all the balls randomly.

Now the program can take any number of balls and place it on the "right" side of a "scale" and then another amount of balls to be placed on the "left" side of the scale. It can read for how much exactly one side is heavier than the another, and then it can proceed to weight another set of balls until he can for sure tell for each numbered ball if it is "light" or "heavy". It should know how to process this in a least "weightings" or "uses of the scale" as possible.

So the goal is to write the most efficient program that can most efficiently separate the balls using the minimal amount of "weightings", and doing that for as many cases of given balls as possible.

Comment: This seems too simple. The optimal algorithm is well-known to the point where it's a common interview question. It would just be a race to be the first to implement it in the chosen language.

Comment: @Mego Thank you for your review, Btw How would one write such an algorithm? Does something like that already exists? My main point of posting this was to answer that question, I would appriciate if you have any way of providing any help.

Comment: @Mego The "interview" question you're thinking of is probably a version with one different weight, as pointed out in the linked question. This seems challenging enough; one could even consider comparing different numbers of balls.

Comment: What this needs to be a good question is some kind of output specification, e.g. giving the expected number of comparisons, an interactive protocol with the user giving comparison results, or some kind of tree decision representation.

Comment: I would just set a pivot ball (e.g. the first one) and compare everything else with it. Runtime complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: @Kennylau but that is exactly the oposite of the solution. You would have then too many unecessary weightings, since the goal is to do it in least possible weightings no matter how complex the real solution might be

Answer (score 1):

## How Many Colours?

Take a grid of ASCII art rectangles as input and output the **minimum** number of colours you would need to colour it in so that no two rectangles of the same colour are touching.

### Rules

- Input can be any type of grid format (multine string, array of strings, etc...).
- Rectangles only count as touching if the **inside** is adjacent to the inside of another rectangle (see the bottom-left rectangle in the example).
- You may use different characters to `#` and space, but if you do, please specify what you use in your answer.
- The grid itself will always be rectangular.
- Grid width and height will always be between 3 and 99.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example

The output for this input would be `3`. An example arrangement of each colour `1` to `3` is labelled in the input below. Note how the bottom-left rectangle does not count as adjacent to the middle one.

```
#################
# 1  #      # 1 #
######      #   #
# 2  #  3   #####
#    #      #   #
######      # 2 #
# 3  ########   #
#    #  1   #   #
#################
```

### Test Cases

*TODO...*

#### Links

[Four Colour Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)

#### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Answer (score 1):

## Wheels on the Bus Go...

### Scenario

There is a bus heading for an intersection. Usually that is when buses would stop and give way to traffic, but [there's a bomb on the bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_(1994_film))! The bomb blows up if the speed of the bus falls below 50 miles-per-hour. Find out what speed the bus needs to travel at to avoid crashing into the cars going through the intersection.

### Input

- Take a list of cars coming from the left and another list of cars coming from the right. The lists contain the distance of each car from the intersection as integers.
- The distances will always be from `1` to `99` units.
- There will always be `1` to `9` cars in either direction (`2` to `18` total).

### Output

- The speed the bus must travel to make it through the intersection without hitting a car.
- The speed can be an integer from `5` and to `9` which is the `speed in miles-per-hour / 10`.

### Rules

- Each iteration, every vehicle moves `speed in mph / 10` units forwards. The "path" of a vehicle for each iteration includes it's position before the iteration, it's position after the iteration and every position in between.
- The cars always travel at 40 mph.
- A crash occurs when the path of the bus intersects the path of a car in the intersection.
- The bus starts 20 units before the intersection.
- Cars cannot crash into other cars.
- The speed of each bus cannot change during the simulation. You can only give each bus one speed.
- Only solvable inputs will be given.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example

*TODO: Example doesn't make sense yet. Will complete later...*

Here's an example using ASCII art to illustrate what would happen with this input and a bus speed of 6. Note: despite what it may look like, the intersection should behave as if it's size is only one unit.

- `B` = Bus
- `.` = Vehcile movement during iteration
- `C` = Car

Input: `[ ... ]`

```
                  |     ^ |
                  |   | | |
------------------ ---     --------------
        <-                |    C . . . C
--  --  --  --  --         --  --  --  --
. C           C . |     .  . C     ->
------------------     --- --------------
                  |   |   |
                  |     B |
                  |   | . |
                  |     . |
                  |   | . |
                  |     . |
                  |   | . |
                  |     B |
```

### Test Cases

*TODO...*

#### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [simulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)

Comment: So a bus can never crash with another bus with a different unit digit in the distance, if they are moving from different roads?

Comment: @KennyLau There's only two roads, the sideways one and the up/down one. The only time buses from both roads will crash is if their paths overlap over the intersection. I'll try explaining it better when I edit it.

Answer (score 1):

## From Smiles to Molecular formula!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

[SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) is an algorithm to represent chemical molecules in one-line ASCII.

In this challenge, we will only be dealing with purely organic chemicals.

- All the `H`ydrogens are not represented.
- All single bonds not represented, double bond is `=`, triple bond is `#`. For example, ethane is `CC`, ethene is `C=C`, ethyne is `C#C`.
- Branches are represented by `()`. For example, isobutane is `CC(C)C`, acetone is `CC(=O)C`.
- Cycles are represented by numbers. For example, cyclohexane is `C1CCCCC1`.
- All other things are ignored in this challenge.

Your task is to determine the molecular formula of a molecule, given its SMILES representation.

## Specs

Any reasonable input/output format.

These are all accepted, for formaldehyde:

- `CH2O`
- `C1H2O1`
- `CxHxxOx` (unary)
- `CHHO`
- `OCHH`
- `OHCH`

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Testcases

```
input       output
C=O         CH2O
O=C=O       CO2
C1C(=O)CC1  C4H6O
C#CCC       C4H6
```

Comment: I think you need to tighten up the specs. "Reasonable" is, of course, wide open to interpretation. For example, it's left unclear if the ordering in the output matters. Is it always carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, in that order (omitted if not present, naturally)? Is it "unreasonable" to say `OCH2`?

Comment: @dcsohl Thanks, edited to allow that.

Comment: Are you sure about your examples? My reading of the Wikipedia page is that cyclehexane's SMILES description should contain 6 `C`s, but your example only has 5.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That was a typo, thanks.

Comment: Which elements do answers need to be able to handle?

Comment: Also, can we assume that we won't be given aromatics so complicated that the cycle indication numbers go up to 10?

Answer (score 1):

### The incremental Gijswijt's sequence

[The Gijswijt's sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/generate-n-digits-of-gijswijts-sequence) **G** is a sequence where the next term is the maximal number of repeating blocks of terms going so far backward.

The first numbers of this series are: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3](https://oeis.org/A090822)

The incremental Gijswijt's sequence **I** is a sequence of Gijswijt's indices where any term of this last sequence I(n) has an image in Gijswijt G(I(n)) that is greater or equal all terms that precede it in that sequence G .

In other terms, It is an increasing sequence of indexes i for which G(i) is at least as large as G(j) for any j < i. Thus it contains the index of every 1 up to the first 2, every 2 up to the first 3, etc

Example:

```
  G= 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,...

  I= 1, 2, 3,       6, 7, 8, 9,                        18,                           28,                        37,...
```

Your program must output the most you can print from the starting of sequence until the delay between printing two consecutive terms exceeds 10 minutes, the actual number of outputs is your score.

For matter of reliability, the complete accurate "run-lengthed" G sequence must be linked through pastbin or any raw data repository.

the output will be so large to fit an int32 registry, so i suggest to print it modulo 1000007 or dont.

if the scores are not be divergent enough i will apply some salt, scoring is evaluated to N/T where T is executon time in seconds for the last term of sequence, the tie broken by the earlier post .

Only another 45 secs after the delay cap are given as an extra time.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I would VTC as unclear.

Comment: hmmm what is unclear ?

Comment: Winning criterion. `until nothing appears in the console for 10 minutes` is a bit vague.

Comment: 10 minutes from last output, is this what u asked me to clarify ?

Comment: "nothing appears" is a bit vague. I think you want something more like "the time to calculate the next term is > 10 minutes."

Comment: yes when it exceeds that cap, execution must be halted

Comment: .. I mean the wording in unclear. Can you say something like the time to calculate rather than the console is empty?

Comment: if that makes you contented ....

Comment: I found the definition rather hard to follow, and technically it defines an uncountable number of sequences. I suggest "*The incremental Gijswijt's sequence is the (increasing) sequence of indexes `i` for which `G(i)` is at least as large as `G(j)` for any `j < i`. Thus it contains the index of every `1` up to the first `2`, every `2` up to the first `3`, etc. If you are familiar with the Records transform on integer sequences, this is effectively a Non-strict Records transform.*"

Comment: "*For matter of reliability, the complete accurate "run-lengthed" G sequence must be linked through pastbin or any raw data repository.*" Why? If it's generated by the same process, it would have the same bugs. If it isn't, I don't see the point of asking every single answer to include a pastebin link. "*i suggest to print it modulo 1000007 or dont.*" Either make this a requirement or don't. It complicates comparison of answers to make it optional. "*Only another 45 secs after the delay cap are given as an extra time.*" Extra time for what?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. That is because it a contest for scores in increment, so any new record must be followed by a string of compressed numbers from the last terminus reached, until the new record using his own technique imagine the new score is 2 numbers far from the last result ? the algorithm must print a correct G series that is ground of I series.

Comment: 2. The numbers could be too big and unintelligible, so either print a remainder or the difference of two edges or print it all along the console modulo something.

Comment: 3. extra time for me to stop execution.

Comment: a compressed string of numbers * in the first note

Answer (score 1):

### Functional Programming in Your Language

A lot of modern programming languages allow some form of functional programming, but I don't often see them used. I'm curious to see how different languages tackle problems that are naturally solved with some form of functional programming. The winning entry to this contest will have the shortest total code as measured in bytes for these four questions

1. Given a three-part list, return a list containing only those members for which the third element is a string.

   sampleIn1={{1,2,"fred"},{3,2,1.23},{3,2,"this one too",1.23},{},{"apple","banana",{1,2,3}}}

   sampleOut1={{1,2,"fred"},{3,2,"this one too",1.23}}
2. Given a list of lists, each sub-list known to have exactly two elements, both of which are numbers, return a list of the first element in each sublist multiplied by the absolute value of the second.

   sampleIn2={{3,4},{-1,3},{1.0,-3}};

   sampleOut2={12,-3,3.0}

In the sample output above I distinguish between integer and real output; in practice you can treat everything as a real number if you prefer.

3. Given a list known to be composed only of numbers, return a list of the cube of each member, sorted by the square of each member (or its absolute value, which will have the same result).

   sampleIn3={1,-2,0.5,4};

   sampleOut3={.125,1,-8,64}
4. Given a list known to be composed only of numbers, return a list with each member of the list divided by the number before it. Since this is undefined for the first number in the input list, that element should be omitted. Where division by zero would result, the list should include notification of exception ("N/A" or something similar as befits your language of choice).

   sampleIn4={1,-2,0,5,4};

   sampleOut4={-2,0,"N/A",0.8}

Presume that input has been assigned to a variable `a` in the natural list format for your language, assuming it has one.

To be clear, you don't *have* to use abstract functions or lambda calculus here, though I suspect that in many languages this will provide a short solution.

Standard rules apply, the examples above are only examples. Your code should work for arbitrary input.

Comment: This challenge [explicitly disallows arbitrary classes of languages](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/45941), is a [do X without Y challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/45941), and a [multi-part challenge with no interaction between the parts](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8464/45941). The latter is not allowed on PPCG, and the others are highly discouraged.

Comment: @Mego Read again, I explicitly allow any technique in any type of language.

Comment: I misread. This is still a multi-part challenge, which are not allowed.

Comment: @Mego I can combine the challenges. Do you have any other objections or suggestions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the challenges *are* combined.  Anyways, the challenge feels like a random list of arbitrary, unrelated tasks.  I think perhaps challenge #4 could stand on its own (especially if you made the operator a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest path to the exit:

- Given a `n*n` grid of 3 symbolic characters `{'.','#',*}` , where `n` is inputted, the dot is a safe spot to move from/to, `#` is a dragon who blows fire and spits magma, `*` is the outlet . Define (if it can be) the shortest path to take from the extreme upper/right to the star character that a moving point can take where:

  `m` is an integer `m < n` given by user-input or a function dimention with `n`, that generates obstacles `#` at the dynamic point `m modulus n` from the starting point, the last `#` point so far is replaced by an exit `*`, if no such path exists print `0` or a negative amount or `undifined`/`null` anything witch doesnt throw an error.

**Testcases:**

```
input: 7,3
output:9
```

why? the input generates this grid

```
...#...
#...#..
.#...#.
..#...#
...#...
#...*..
```

The shortest path is marked as _

```
__.#...
#__.#..
.#__.#.
..#__.#
...#_..
#..._..
```

More TODO ...

**Hints/notes**

- Solution is cyclic
- No solutions when m+1 divides n or n-1 . (to verify)

Comment: Like I said in your other challenge, please use proper English grammar and spelling.

Comment: This looks like a standard path-finding, which we've already done.  Making every `m`th place also make an obstacle doesn't make it sufficiently different IMO

Comment: @NathanMerrill how is so ? obstacles are systematically generated but not arbitrarily

Comment: Hmmm...I guess that *does* allow for optimizations.  Yeah, this would work for a code-golf.  You should define what happens if there is no solution, or guarantee that there will always be a solution.

Comment: The text says that the start is the extreme upper/right, but the example seems to start from the upper left. Do you mean upper left? Also the slash makes it look like upper or right, rather than referring to a corner, which doesn't seem consistent with the example.

Comment: @trichoplax this is not really a big issue, up/right to down/left or up/left do down/right.

Comment: @Agawa001 It's no issue either way - I'm just helping get it clear which one you want before the challenge goes live

Comment: @trichoplax the challenge will never get a soul to the other end anyways i m not really ready for another blizzard of downvotes

Comment: I never know which challenges will make it to main. I just try to help clarify them until we can tell one way or the other

Comment: I dont know why serial dvter did miss to star the 4th comment, is it because is not castigating !

Comment: I think you have a gross misunderstanding of what constitutes serial downvoting. Serial downvoting is when somebody goes through and downvotes a lot of posts, typically out of spite. I downvoted both this and your other sandboxed post because they are very poorly specified, and you seem to have a tenuous grasp on the English language that makes understanding these challenges impossible.

Comment: [that's penguins being penguins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXY-3Cuo9pE)

Answer (score 1):

## Simulate a DNA Computer [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

DNA computers are very powerful computational models, theoretically able to solve NP-complete problems such as SAT deterministically in polynomial time. Your task in this challenge is to write a program/function that simulates the behaviour of a very simple DNA computer that accepts only four different kinds of commands.

## DNA and Tubes

To make things a bit easier, we model *DNA strands* as non-empty words over {0,1}. So for our purpose, the following are all valid strands of DNA: `1`, `010010`, `01`, `1100101`.

Our DNA computer has access to an infinite number of *(test) tubes* T<sub>1</sub>,T<sub>2</sub>,T<sub>3</sub>,..., each of which contains a finite number of DNA strands. That is, T<sub>i</sub> ⊂ {0,1}<sup>*</sup> for all i ∈ ℕ<sup>+</sup>. For example, T<sub>1</sub> = {`1`,`0100101`,`000`} would be a valid tube. At the beginning of a simulation, all tubes are assumed to be empty (T<sub>i</sub> = ∅ for all i ∈ ℕ<sup>+</sup>).

---

## Commands

Our computer supports four different commands: *Initialize* (`I`),  *Merge* (`M`), *Filter* (`F`), and *Amplify* (`A`). In the following, let the pairwise different numbers i, j, k ∈ ℕ<sup>+</sup> denote indices of tubes T<sub>i</sub>, T<sub>j</sub> and T<sub>k</sub>. Furthermore, let n ∈ ℕ<sup>+</sup> and b ∈ {0,1}.

### Initialize

- **Description**: We take all possible DNA strands of length `n` and put them into tube `i`.
- **Syntax**: `i = I n`
- **Semantics**: T<sub>i</sub> ← {0,1}<sup>n</sup>
- **Example**: After the execution of `2 = I 3`, we have T<sub>2</sub> = {`000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, `110`, `111`}.

### Merge

- **Description**: We mix the contents of tubes `j` and `k` and put them into tube `i`.
- **Syntax**: `i = M j k`
- **Semantics**: T<sub>i</sub> ← T<sub>j</sub> ∪ T<sub>k</sub> ; T<sub>j</sub> ← ∅ ; T<sub>k</sub> ← ∅
- **Example**: If T<sub>2</sub> = {`00`, `111`} and T<sub>3</sub> = {`1`, `010`, `00`}, then after the execution of `1 = M 2 3`, we have T<sub>1</sub> = {`00`, `111`, `1`, `010`} and T<sub>2</sub> = T<sub>3</sub> = ∅.

### Filter

- **Description**: We remove all DNA strands from tube `j` whose `n`-th bit is not equal to `b`. We put the remaining strands into tube `i`.
- **Syntax**: `i = F j n b`
- **Semantics**: T<sub>i</sub> ← T<sub>j</sub> ∩ {0,1}<sup>n-1</sup>∘{b}∘{0,1}<sup>*</sup> ; T<sub>j</sub> ← ∅
- **Example**: If T<sub>2</sub> = {`1010000`, `111`, `1`, `0101`}, then after the execution of `1 = F 2 3 1`, we have T<sub>1</sub> = {`1010000`, `111`} and T<sub>2</sub> = ∅

### Amplify

- **Description**: We put an exact copy of the contents of tube `j` into tube `i`.
- **Syntax**: `i = A j`
- **Semantics**: T<sub>i</sub> ← T<sub>j</sub>
- **Example**: If T<sub>2</sub> = {`1010000`, `111`, `1`, `0101`}, then after the execution of `1 = A 2`, we have both T<sub>1</sub> = {`1010000`, `111`, `1`, `0101`} and T<sub>2</sub> = {`1010000`, `111`, `1`, `0101`}.

---

## Input

Input will be a *DNA program*, i.e. a sequence of these four commands, that can be read  from STDIN, taken as a function argument or even be stored in a file. It's up to you whether you take them as a list or a string with some kind of separator. Also, you can choose a different separator for the parameters of the commands or encode each command as a list as long as you do so consistently. For example, instead of the command `1 = F 5 10 0`, you may use `[1,"F",5,10,0]`, `1;F/5/10/0`, `1=F(5,10,0)` or the like. 
You may assume that the input is always syntactically correct. For example input/output pairs, see below.

---

## Output

You have to output a truthy value iff tube 1 is not empty (i.e. T<sub>1</sub> ≠ ∅) after the execution of the DNA program specified in the input. Otherwise output a falsey value. Note that you are not actually required to simulate the DNA program step by step - if you find a more clever way to calculate the output of a given program, feel free to use it.

---

## Examples

In the below examples, all commands are `;`-separated and encoded as described in the "Commands" section.

**Truthy**

- `1 = I 20`
- `2 = I 4; 1 = A 2`
- `3 = I 1; 1 = M 3 9`
- `1 = I 4; 2 = A 1; 3 = F 1 1 0; 4 = F 3 2 0; 5 = F 2 1 1; 5 = M 3 4; 1 = M 2 5`
- `1 = I 3; 2 = A 1; 3 = A 1; 4 = A 1; 5 = F 2 1 1; 6 = F 3 2 0; 7 = F 4 3 1; 2 = M 6 7; 1 = M 2 5; 2 = A 1; 3 = A 1; 4 = F 2 1 0; 5 = F 3 2 1; 1 = M 4 5` (<sup>1</sup>)

**Falsey**

- (the empty program)
- `2 = I 5`
- `1 = I 2; 2 = A 1; 3 = F 1 2 0; 2 = A 3; 1 = F 2 2 1`
- `1 = I 1; 2 = I 1; 3 = M 1 2`
- `1 = M 2 3`

---

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case you are interested: this example evaluates the formula (x<sub>1</sub> ∨ ¬x<sub>2</sub> ∨ x<sub>3</sub>) ∧ (¬x<sub>1</sub> ∨ x<sub>2</sub>), that is, the contents of T<sub>1</sub> after execution of the program are exactly the assignments to (x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>3</sub>) that make this formula true. One can create similar such programs for any 3SAT formula. The number of commands needed is linear in the size of the given formula.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from being written in a more layman-friendly and less symbolic way. While I might know that `Ti ⊂ {0,1}*` means that each test tube is a subset of the kleene star of the set `{0, 1}` I don't think every user of this site will. You also use things like `ℕ+` instead of saying, say, "positive integers" and so on. This is just my personal opinion, but I think if you can explain something with words instead of symbols without compromising much in terms of length, you are more likely to be understood when using words.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for a `king-of-the-hill` challenge:

You have a "memory arena" with a fixed size.  You have several programs which "reside" in the memory arena (I mean you take the assembly and put it in the arena).  The goal of the game is to get another program to access memory outside of this "arena" which then causes it to die because access outside of the memory arena is not defined.  The last program standing wins.

You enter in assembly code (I have not determined which architecture yet).  At the beginning of a round all of the entries get randomly placed in the memory arena.  Each program will execute one instruction per turn.

It would be very similar to [red code](http://www.corewars.org/) but in actual assembler.

Please feel free to post comments

Comment: Related because of your mention of core war, although I wouldn't consider it a duplicate:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47581/the-nano-core-war

Answer (score 1):

### Kill the mosketeers

Taken a `NxN` square field, where you are supposed to be on the extreme upper right corner, `n` mosketeers are waiting an execution instruction that begins with the first lefttmost shooter alternatively until the last righttmost one, in a continuous unceasable order, meanwhile, between any shot and another you are allowed to move one step either  to 4 allowed perpendicular directions.

`T` a period permitted to reload the riffle from a shot to another, dependently of steps taken from a move to another, a step is expressed in other words, as the time taken from two consecutive shots that of a mosketeer and his neighbor, so once T steps are elapsed, the mosketeer takes turn to shot again where two shots can occur in real-time.

Your task, is more than saving your head on your shoulders, but it is rather the ability of killing all the mosketeers while they are reloading their riffles by a knife, **noted** that : a mosketeer can shot in an horizontal dimention if his turn comes out, and no moketeer is between him and you, morover, a  mosketeer do never move.

Given two inputs, `N` `T`, say in term of integer output how many mosketeers you are able to kill, return `-1` or nil the case you end up killed no matter what you tried.

### Example:

**input:**

```
   4,3
```

**steps:**

```
...*  |... .|.. ..|. |..| .|.. ..|. |..| .|.. ..|. ...| .... ....
....  |..* .|.. ..|. |..| .|.. ..|. |..| .|.. ..|. ...| .... ....
....  |... .|.* ..|* |.*| .|*. .*|. |*.| *|.. ..|. ...| .... ....
$$$$  |$$$ $|$$ $$|$ |$$| $|$$ $$|$ |$$| $|$$ *$$$ .*$| ..*$ ...*
```

**Output:**

```
  4
```

---

**example 2**

**input:**

```
   4,2
```

**steps:**

```
...*  |... .|.. |.|. .|.| |... .|.| |... .|.| .... .|.| 
....  |..* .|.. |.|. .|.| |... .|.| |... .|.| .... .|.| 
....  |... .|.* |.|* .|*| |... .|*| |*.. *|.| .... *|.| 
$$$$  |$$$ $|$$ |$|$ $|$| |$*$ $$.$ $$.$ $$.$ *$.$ .$.$
```

**Output:**

```
  2
```

---

Comment: 1) Do you mean musketeers? 2) I think the diagrams could do with a bit of explaining - it took me a while to decipher that `|` meant shooting, `$` is a musketeer, `*` is you and the spaces separated different states. 3) It's not obvious to me why it's not possible to get all four musketeers in the second case, and also more test cases would be good (especially some that result in `-1`)

Comment: @Sp3000 i m sorry to puzzle u this way beucause the challenge isnt about deceiphering patterns, but honestly i think that goes without saying, the second part where yu have been stuck deceiphering it, the two remaing shooters cannot be killed because either of both can shoot you horizontally when you are busy stabbing the other.

Comment: any ways, you dont have to boggle yur mind more this will gonna be dead on meta,

Answer (score 1):

## Collatz or Hailstone sequence efficiently

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Sorry for everywhere I posted in the wrong place and thank you to all of the mods for helping me find the sandbox.

---

Winner is the shortest run time to check whether all numbers up to N will end in x=1 or goes 70 iterations without returning to the original number or without decreasing under a step over Log(N) steps in a row under iterating f(x)=x/2 if x is even and f(x)=(3x+1)/2 if x is odd.

Hint: all one needs to show is that for all x under iteration it hits another y in the sequence that has already been shown to hit 1.

---

## Sandbox questions

- How can I phrase the above challenge. I set it with parameters that halt for all natural numbers n. I care more about the speed of the program then the shortness of the program.

Comment: Glad to see you've found the Sandbox now. I know it's somewhat counterintuitive that these are posted as answers instead of questions, but it keeps them all in once place with more chance the people who are looking to give feedback will find them.

Comment: For code that is judged by its speed, rather than its length, we have the fastest-code tag. I've added this and a few other tags. You can click on the tags to see other questions of the same type, and a description of the tag. Feel free to use different tags - I've just added some as suggestions.

Comment: I've removed the `$`s since currently [this site does not support MathJax or LaTeX](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/do-we-really-want-latex-mathjax-right-now). Your challenge seems to work without it, but if you ever need mathematical notation I've found [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/) can be used as a workaround (it's fiddly so I'd only recommend it where the mathematical notation is essential).

Comment: I've looked at the [challenges containing the word Collatz](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=collatz+is%3Aq) and it seems they are mostly code-golf (shortest code) challenges and there have been no fastest-code challenges so far, so I expect this challenge will not be a duplicate.

Comment: What form should the output take? Just true or false? Or the number of cases that don't get to 1 in 70 steps? I guess the latter will prevent all cases above a certain N having identical output.

Comment: The biggest problem I see with this challenge being [tag:fastest-code] is that I don't see any real optimisation potential beyond the "hinted" memoization. Do you believe anything other than actually including memoization will affect runtime significantly? If not then this feels very much like a chameleon challenge for "write an efficient memoization function" and most of the answers will probably have unappreciably different time taken.

Comment: there are a lot of shortcuts to the clever person for instance if x is of the form 2^k then we're done,  similarly if x of form 2^k-1 it will ascend k times in. row, so there are number theoretical optimization other then the hint stated

Comment: the output should be the numbers under n the fail conditions. i.e. n that doesn't hit one,doesn't cycle in 70 terms, doesn't run for more the Log (n)/Log (2). that is Log base 2 of N.

Comment: Just so you know, you are getting notifications because this is your post. Other people won't be notified unless you put an @ symbol before their name in your post, like @FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: oh thank you, @trichoplax I responded what inputs should be

Comment: Also note, neither of the optimisations you propose would actually improve the speed of a program that computes this. The Collatz operations are so trivial that calling them `k` times is faster than checking if a number is a natural power of 2. In addition, if you have memoisation you will only ever have to do each power of two once, rather than check each number for a non-trivial property.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes for those examples but this does not convince me that there are no shortcuts for the smart programmer hence the challanhe

Comment: This site isn't quite like other SE sites, I don't believe you should post a challenge if you yourself are not certain that there actually is challenge. That said, I'd guess the actual best approach is to grow a collatz tree upwards and just report the number of nodes that satisfy your properties, but that has the same problems of it being pretty much optimal already: I feel like the differences between responses would be largely negligible. Someone may prove me wrong, but until you know the competition will be worthwhile, I'd recommend against posting on the main site.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Are there other SE you would recommend I ask?

Comment: No this is the correct site for this question, I just don't think it would be particularly good. You have enough rep to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) by the way, it may be worth finding some other people's opinions; I am not the sole authority on the goodness of questions ;)

Comment: @shaihorowitz If you edit your challenge to reflect the answers you have commented with then it will be nearer to a finished post and people can comment on the complete specification.

Comment: Algorithmically, I also can't see any obvious ways of speeding it up, although that doesn't mean there aren't any. However, this will be a program on a real machine, not just an abstract algorithm. As such compromises will have to be made and I would expect there to be a variety of ways of speeding up the code that may vary considerably between languages. Where I have posted optimisation challenges the techniques used were not at all obvious to me until I saw the solutions, so I think this could be an interesting challenge.

Comment: Just a note - I think how the challenge will play out might depend on the exact value of `N` chosen here...

Comment: It might be worth including a rule about hardcoding. Do you want to allow no hardcoding at all, or only the first m values, for some m you define in the challenge?

Answer (score 1):

## Scry sort

In Magic the Gathering, your library is a stack of cards, the effect Scry 2 causes you to take the top two cards of your library and arrange them as you choose on the top and/or bottom of your library.

[image]

You have six total choices:

- Put both cards on top in either order
- Put one cards on the bottom and one on top
- Put both cards on the bottom in either order

If you are able to Scry 2 at will, you can repeatedly do so to arrange your library in any order. In this challenge, the cards of your library will be numbered from 1 to n, and your goal will be to arrange them in sorted order.

---

What should be the challenge here?

- Code golf to find the minimum number of Scry 2's needed
- Code golf to find any sequence that arranges your library, no matter how long
- Fastest code or code challenge to sort in as few Scry 2's as possible.

Comment: I like the code challenge idea, but I think maybe it could be improved with *Scry X* instead of a constant 2. Given a nice range of cases to test, of course.

Comment: I think this depends a lot on whether there's an efficient algorithm or not. If there is, then code golf for optimal solution with a time limit might be good. Otherwise, code golf for optimal solution will just be plain BFS or something. Likewise, if there is an efficient algorithm, then fastest code might not be so good. As long as you don't know how easily this can be solved optimally, I'd probably go with code golf without requiring optimality.

Comment: Obviously in M:tG you don't generally know the order of your library, but it's not clear to me whether you're proposing that we would.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was considering both for the code challenge. Finding out what cards are in your deck as you go and optimizing for expectation might be more interesting than trying to solve the whole configuration at once.

Comment: Funnily enough I was just thinking of posting this as a challenge (as a fastest-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

## Matching a string using a huge number of steps

[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Your task is to write a regex that matches a string you defined in as close to **`n`** steps as is humanly possible.

The regex must match the whole string without the `g`lobal flag on.

## Scoring

The score would be `regex length` + `string length` + `absolute difference between the number of steps and n`.

For example, if `n` = 65536, [this example](https://regex101.com/r/mL6gS1/1) has 6 bytes as regex, 49152 bytes in the string, and 65539 steps, which would account for a total score of 6+49152+3=49161.

Lowest score wins.

## Requirements

1. `n` = 65536 (`2**16`)
2. `n` = 59049 (`3**10`)
3. `n` = 40320 (`8!`)

The total score will calculated from the scores of the three programs.

#### Questions:

- How can I make this challenge better?

Comment: Wouldn't the score be 6 + 49152 + 3 for your example?

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding.

Comment: fyi if you don't end up allowing undershooting, the `absolute difference...` part should probably be `(number of steps - 65536)`

Comment: Also, can we have a regex which theoretically gives a number of steps we can prove, but doesn't work in practice (e.g. due to insufficient memory)?

Comment: What is a step? Whatever it is, it seems uninteresting as we can do an empty string with `(){65536}` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

## International Choice of Urinal Protocol efficiency

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A long while ago, Randall Munroe of xkcd fame wrote a blog post entitled [Urinal protocol vulnerability](https://blog.xkcd.com/2009/09/02/urinal-protocol-vulnerability/). The titular "International Choice of Urinal Protocol" is that when men enter a bathroom that has a row of urinals along the wall, they will first take the end urinals, and then take the urinals that are furthest from the other men. All men seek to avoid awkwardness, which happens when two men use adjacent urinals.

For example, if there are five urinals in a row, then by following this protocol, men will take urinals in this order:

```
UUUUU
1 3 2
```

In this case, the packing efficiency is optimal. However, when there are seven urinals, then this happens:

```
UUUUUUU
1  3  2
```

This is essentially the worst case. Fewer than half of the urinals are used, and Randall continues investigating when the best and worst cases happen. For this challenge, though, your only task is to calculate the packing efficiency of this protocol when given a number `n` of urinals, which is `k/n` where `k` is the number of urinals taken before awkwardness ensues.

### Spec

- [Standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.
- Input is a single positive integer `n`, which may be given as either decimal or unary.
- Output must be either a float or a simplified fraction. If your language cannot do either of these easily (e.g. BF or Retina), then you may simply output `k` (in decimal or unary).

### Test cases

**Decimal**

```
 1 1.0
 2 0.5
 3 0.6666666666666666
 4 0.5
 5 0.6
 6 0.5
 7 0.42857142857142855
 8 0.5
 9 0.5555555555555556
10 0.5
```

**Fractions**

```
 1 1/1 {or} 1
 2 1/2
 3 2/3
 4 1/2
 5 3/5
 6 1/2
 7 3/7
 8 1/2
 9 5/9
10 1/2
```

**Urinals taken `k`**

```
 1 1
 2 1
 3 2
 4 2
 5 3
 6 3
 7 3
 8 4
 9 5
10 5
```

*Note: this is [A166079](https://oeis.org/A166079).*

*Related: [The Urinal Protocol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47952/the-urinal-protocol), which asks for all the possible ways men could take urinals with no restriction on the first and no awkwardness.*

Comment: Did you mean `8 1/2`?

Comment: You might want to link to [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A166079).

Comment: Very related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47952/the-urinal-protocol

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ: Whew! Not a duplicate! :P But thanks for that anyway, I'll include it.

Comment: @KennyLau: Thanks for those!

Answer (score 1):

## Find the smallest number bigger than the input whose digital sum is the input

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

"Digital sum" refers to the sum of all the digits in a number.

For example, the digital sum of `1324` is `10`, because `1+3+2+4 = 10`.

The challenge is to write a program/function to calculate the smallest number bigger than the input whose digital sum is the input.

### Example with walkthrough

As an example, take the number `9` as the input:

```
9 = 1+8 -> 18
9 = 2+7 -> 27
9 = 3+6 -> 36
...
9 = 8+1 -> 81
9 = 9+0 -> 90
```

The valid output would be the smallest number above, which is `18`.

### Specs

Note that `9` is not the valid output for this example, because the reversed number must be greater than the original number.

Note that the input will be positive.

### Test-Cases:

```
 2 => 11
 8 => 17
12 => 39
16 => 79
24 => 699
32 => 5999
```

### References:

This is [OEIS A161561](http://oeis.org/A161561).

Comment: As far as I know it's either 2 or there is none

Comment: I see what you mean, let me specify this a little better

Comment: I edited the question to include the additional rule and changed the term digital root with digital sum

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the mentioned part?

Comment: Could I edit the question for you? You can rollback the edit afterwards if you don't like it.

Comment: You are welcome to. This is my first Challenge I post here

Comment: Done. How's it now?

Comment: Also, you are welcome to [join our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I meant. thank you

Comment: "*because the reversed number must be greater than the original number.*" I don't know what you mean by this. Do you mean the *output* number must be greater than the input number?

Comment: Yes it has to be greater. If you look at the examples you can see it: input 9 and output has to be a number which has at least two numbers which have 9 as its sum.

Comment: Can I post this abandoned proposal?

Answer (score 1):

## Light the Way!

This is based on the [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) game. There is a grid of tiles, and clicking on a tile (performing a "move") toggles the state of the clicked tile as well as the (orthogonally) adjacent tiles. **This variation will also toggle the diagonally adjacent tiles.**

It is helpful to note that (on a board with only two states) all moves commute, so the order in which they are performed is not important. It follows that performing a collection of moves a second time will undo what was done the first time.

*There are a few ways to present this challenge, so I'll describe some possibilities. Let me know what you think. The challenge could be one of the below:*

- Given a board size `n` (optional) and the initial state of the n-by-n board, determine an optimal collection of moves that will toggle every lit ("on") tile into its dark ("off") state.
- Given `n` and a sequence of moves performed on an initially dark board of size `n`, provide the resulting matrix of states.
- A variation on the above involving graphical output.

Input format would be flexible. `n >= 1`.

---

#### Snippet to show how the game works:

The board size may be adjusted in the first input field. The second field (functionality added by Conor O'Brien) will take a list of coordinates (`[[0,0],[1,2],[3,0],...]`) and perform the moves for you.

```js
var table;
var color1 = "aqua",
 color2 = "yellow";
var moveList = [];

window.onload = function () {
 table = document.getElementById("lightGame");
 buildTable();

 var updateButton = document.getElementById("updateButton");
 if (updateButton) {
  updateButton.onclick = buildTable;
 }

 // added by Conor O'Brien
 document.getElementById("perform").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var toPerf = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("moves").value);
  //console.log(toPerf);
  function rec(arr) {
   var m = arr.shift();
   var x = m[0],
    y = m[1];
   var cell = table.rows[y].cells[x];
   update(cell);
   if (arr.length) {
    setTimeout(rec, 500, arr);
   }
  }
  rec(toPerf);
 });
};

function buildTable() {
 // get size
 var input = document.getElementById("size");
 var size = new Number(input && input.value || 5);
 
 var rows = size,
  cols = size;
 
 // clear moves
 moveList = [];
 moveHolder.innerHTML = "[]";
 
 // remove existing rows
 while (table.lastChild) {
  table.removeChild(table.lastChild);
 }
 
 // create new rows
 for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  
  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
   var cell = document.createElement("td");
   cell.style.backgroundColor = color1;
   cell.x = x;
   cell.y = y;
   cell.onclick = function () {
    update(this);
   };
   row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  table.appendChild(row);
 }
}

function update(cell) {
 var x = cell.x;
 var y = cell.y;
 
 var xMax = table.rows[0].cells.length;
 var yMax = table.rows.length;
 
 // update cell
 changeColor(cell);
 
 // update orthogonally adjacent
 if (x > 0) changeColor(table.rows[y].cells[x - 1]);
 if (x + 1 < xMax) changeColor(table.rows[y].cells[x + 1]);
 if (y > 0) changeColor(table.rows[y - 1].cells[x]);
 if (y + 1 < yMax) changeColor(table.rows[y + 1].cells[x]);
 
 // update diagonally adjacent
 if (x > 0 && y > 0) changeColor(table.rows[y - 1].cells[x - 1]);
 if (x > 0 && y + 1 < yMax) changeColor(table.rows[y + 1].cells[x - 1]);
 if (x + 1 < xMax && y > 0) changeColor(table.rows[y - 1].cells[x + 1]);
 if (x + 1 < xMax && y + 1 < yMax) changeColor(table.rows[y + 1].cells[x + 1]);
 
 // update moves
 // added by Conor O'Brien
    moveList.push([x, y]);
    moveHolder.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(moveList);
}

function changeColor(cell) {
 cell.style.backgroundColor = cell.style.backgroundColor === color1 ? color2 : color1;
}

function getStyle(elt, styleProp) {
 if (elt.currentStyle)
  return elt.currentStyle[styleProp];
 return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elt, null)[styleProp];
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: darkslategray;
 color: white;
}
#gameDiv {
 text-align: center;
}
header {
 margin: 25px;
}
h2, h4 {
 color: red;
 text-shadow: -2px -2px black;
}

#lightGame {
 border: 1px solid white;
 margin: auto;
}
#lightGame td {
 /*background-color: aqua;*/
 padding: 1px;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
}
#updateDiv {
 margin: 25px;
}
button {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

#autoMoveDiv {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}
footer small {
 color: cyan;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
}
img {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameDiv">
 <header>
  <h2>Light Game</h2>
 </header>
 <div>
  <table id="lightGame">
  </table>
 </div>
 <div id="updateDiv">
  <input id="size" name="size" type="number" min="1" max="20" pattern="\d{1,2}" value="5" required />
  <button id="updateButton" type="button">Update</button>
 </div>
 <div>
  Your moves: <span id="moveHolder">[]</span>
 </div>
 <div id="autoMoveDiv">
  Auto move: 
  <input id="moves" />
  <button id="perform" type="button">Do Moves</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

[Related Questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20lights%20off)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od3yy7s2/4/) of the snippet I made.

Comment: Option 1 would be a [duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/lights-out-find-the-solution) IMO.  I do like option 2, though.

Comment: I agree with Nathan Merrill.

Comment: @NathanMerrill This does include diagonals too, so it's different. But I don't know how different that'd be programmatically.

Comment: Does the board wrap?

Comment: Option two sounds like it's pretty much a duplicate of [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1899/14215), though. Except for the initial board state and diagonals, that is.

Comment: Does it need further variation? Hexagonal board? 3d? Broader effect? Random effect? Context dependent effect?

Comment: I'd definitely make diagonals bold.  I completely missed that when reading.  I think diagonals make either 1 or 2 unique.

Comment: @trichoplax The board does not wrap.

Comment: "Given a board size `n` (optional) and the initial state of the n-by-n board, determine an optimal collection of moves that will toggle every lit ('on') tile into its dark ('off') state." Or you can have "determine an optimal collection of moves that will toggle every lit tile into its dark state *and vice versa*".

Comment: @msh210 If the goal is to toggle every tile, the solution is trivial. If the goal is merely to end with all light, then with all dark, getting from one to the other is also trivial (it's the set of all moves minus the set from the first answer).

Answer (score 1):

### Array of Integers to Array of Digits

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given an array of arbitrary length containing only integers, output an array of integers of each digit of each integer in the array.

**Notes**

- The input array will only consist of integers in base 10
- The integers will be in the range of [0, MAX_INT] where MAX_INT is the greatest value an integer can have in your language
- Assume that all integers will be positive, however you can interpret the integers as signed or unsigned
- String manipulation and the use of any regex is banned by default
- The outputted array must be exactly 1 deep and contain only integers
- The order of the digits in the outputted array must be exactly as they were in the inputted array
- Leading zeros are to be stripped, as they should be when parsed as an integer

**Examples**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[123, 456, 789, 101112] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 000, 000123] -> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3] //'000' is treated as '0' and '000123' is treated as '123'
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward, but pretty trivial in most languages.  (Trivial does *not* mean off topic, but you will likely get lots of answers, as well as some downvotes).  You should specify that the integers are in base 10.

Comment: Will the input array contain `0` or negative integers?

Comment: You say integers, but I take it you mean positive integers?

Comment: I updated the specification

Comment: You should clarify that leading zeros are stripped, so that people don't need to infer that from the last test case.

Comment: What leading zeroes? Numbers can't have them if they are not strings. Is it an array of numbers or array of strings?

Comment: It may be interesting to ban the use of string manipulation. This would change the challenge a lot, but it will force the answers to be less trivial. (also note that such a challenge may be frowned upon: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/31203)

Comment: You mention signed integers, but none of your examples contain negative numbers. Do we only need to support non-negative numbers? If not you should specify how negative numbers should be handled and add an example to the test cases.

Comment: Personally, I doubt that string manipulation is the easiest way to do this in most languages? I don't think banning it improves the question. It just seems to make a bunch of languages unusuable, and the rest just entirely ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

## `fix show`

Your task is given n, you must print first n character returned from Haskell expression `fix show`.

Let me explain how `fix show` produces the "magic" string.

`show` is just escaping the string and then add quote. Since the resulting string consists only double quotes and backslash, `show` then essentially just put backslash before every character then quote the resulting string.

```
show str = '"' : concat ( zipWith (\x y->[x,y]) (repeat '\\') str ) ++ "\"" -- Well, this is not what prelude give, but
```

`fix` is, well, fixpoint combinator. But thanks for laziness, it won't do a infinite loop first.

The string is equivalent to the string defined below:

Assuming there is a series of string. The first string is `""` and the next series is just application of `show` to previous string:

""
    "\"\""
    "\"\\"\\"\""
    "\"\\"\\\\"\\\\"\\"\""
    "\"\\"\\\\"\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\"\\\\"\\"\""

For all n, there is k so that for all l above k, n-th character of l-th string from series is same. That character is the n-th character of `fix show`

TODO: I hate the sentence above, please fix it.

The first 100 character in resulting string

```
"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

So, another implementation is

```
fixshow = '"' : zip (repeat '\') fixshow ++ "\""
```

### Rules

1. You are not allowed to use function `fix`, `show`, and the equivalent functions.
2. Shortest answer wins.

### Sandbox question

Is there another way to prevent answer like `flip take$fix show`, or without importing `f k=k$f k;j n=take n$f show`. And how about array programming language like APL, J and Jelly?

Comment: Your construction doesn't work because `zip` doesn't intersperse the characters, but creates a list of tuples. I think the backslashes also need escaping. It would be helpful to explain that the number of backslashes in sequence goes `1,3,7,15,...` with numbers one less than powers of two. It would be a shame to eliminate all languages with lazy evaluation or generators. It's also vague. Python has generators but they are totally useless here. Even Haskell needs a costly import to get `fix`.

Comment: The output should start `"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"`.

Comment: Language-specific questions are not likely to make much challenge acceptors.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ This question isn't language specific, it just involves implementing a particular Haskell program in any other language. That said, it was a bit hard to figure out what was going on as someone who doesn't really know Haskell.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman This should be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: seems like a cool challenge, but instead of trying to explain lazy evaluation, just define `show` rigorously, and then say the challenge is to output the limit of applying `show` `n` times on the empty string. also, your output is wrong.

Comment: @proudhaskeller when you say the limit of applying show n times, do you mean result of applying show infinite times on ""?

Comment: @xnor 1. I just hate the answer `flip take$fix show`. How do I avoid it? 2. Fixed.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan no, because there is no such thing, applying infinite times. instead, if you have a series of strings, first the empty string, then applying once, then twice, and so on, and at each string look at the `i`th character, from some point on it will be identical in all the strings of the series, and the `i`th character of the limit will be this character.

Comment: @proudhaskeller Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: The implementation with `zipWith`. Maybe you could just ban the command `show` and equivalents? I think implementing it and a a pseudo-fix would be interesting and not definitely better than concatenating powers-of-2-sized blocks.

Comment: *The implementation with `zipWith` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

### Version Comparator

Given two version strings, return a positive, negative or zero value depending on which one is earlier. Version strings consist of one or more non-negative integers separated by full stops, optionally suffixed by a lowercase letter and a final non-negative integer. Examples of versions:

```
1.5a2
1.5b1
1.5
2.19
2.20b
2.20 or 2.20.0 (these should compare equal)
8.1a
8.1
9
10
```

When comparing versions the integers should of course be compared numerically, not lexically. Missing components should compare as zero against numbers, but they compare after letters. You should then be able to recognise that the above versions are in version order, but you can choose whether this should be a positive or negative result. Reversing the parameters should obviously negate the sign of the result, but you can return a different absolute value if you prefer.

Builtins that compare versions are disallowed, but things like regexes are OK.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function wins.

Comment: How do letters compare numerically?

Comment: It should never be necessary.

Comment: Test-cases please. Especially `1a1` vs `1a` vs `1`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Added some more examples. `1a` should compare as if it was `1a0` so less than `1a1` which is less than `1`.

Comment: How do `1a` and `1b` compare?

Comment: @LeakyNun Well, you already know that 1.5a2 compares before 1.5b1...

Answer (score 1):

## Find the duration of a worst-case brute-force attack

Given the following information about a 7-bit ASCII-encoded password and the computer that will crack it with a [brute-force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack):

- Length of the password in characters
- Charset size (i.e total count of the possible characters one character in the password can be)
- Number of passwords the computer can test in one <strike>second</strike> millisecond (rounded down)

Write the shortest program that finds out how long the attack will take in the worst-case scenario where the computer tries all possible passwords.

- The output is the duration in this format: `years months days hours minutes seconds milliseconds`

  - One "month" is 30 days long.
  - Fractions of milliseconds are rounded up.
  - You can assume that the cracking finishes immediately if it takes less than 50 milliseconds, and make the program print out `Instant` in such cases.
  - Similarly, the cracking can be considered `Neverending` if it takes more than 292 billion years.
- The program can output using *any* method, from merely printing to STDOUT to causing a [kernel panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)/[bluescreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) with the duration as the error message.
- The input method to get the info about the password/the machine can be anything, as well. Don't use standard loopholes though.
- It's not enforced, but strongly encouraged to write a standalone program.

Here's how to calculate the charset size:

- Start with 0.
- If there's a digit (in the password), add 10.
- If there's a lowercase letter, add 26.
- If there's an uppercase letter, add another 26.
- If there's punctuation, add 32 (7-bit ASCII has this many punctuation characters).
- If there's a whitespace character, add 2. Whitespace characters are horizontal tab (0x09) and space (0x20).
- Any other character counts as non-printable (including backspace (0x08), `DEL` (0x7F), line feed (0x0A) and carriage return (0x0D)). Add 29 if there's any of them.

Count of all possible passwords is (charset size)<sup>password length</sup>.

Here are some applicable-in-real-life cases you can test your program with (let's assume the computer that will crack them can test 1 billion passwords per second, which equals to 1,000,000 passwords/millisecond):

- 4 characters, charset size 10 (PIN) - 10,000 passwords, output is `0 0 0 0 0 0 1` or `Instant`
- 8 characters, charset size 94 (at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit and one punctuation) - 6,095,689,385,410,816 passwords, output is `0 2 10 13 14 49 386`
- 10 characters, charset size 2 (weakest valid [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) password, contains whitespace only) - 1024 passwords, output is `0 0 0 0 0 0 1` or `Instant`
- 25 characters, charset size 26 ([correcthorsebatterystaple](https://xkcd.com/936/)) - 236,773,830,007,967,588,876,795,164,938,469,376 passwords, output is `7612327353651221350 2 14 0 26 4 939` or `Neverending`
- 127 characters, charset size 96 ([strongest password on newer Windows releases](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/maximum-length-of-password-windows-10)) - written below
- 1024 characters, charset size 36 (4096-bit PGP key represented as a hexadecimal number) - written below

These are the stats of the maximum-strength Windows password:

```
Passwords: 560,333,510,486,846,899,384,847,242,571,130,277,659,458,884,466,874,695,582,912,274,460,529,559,443,783,341,570,989,525,270,653,136,186,432,110,439,597,936,820,880,106,519,625,601,191,574,799,863,912,148,304,962,133,852,037,202,160,056,511,510,962,873,278,300,126,526,144,267,006,137,180,032,492,751,016,171,207,701,495,935,943,049,216
Output: 18014837657113133339276210216407223432981574217685014647084370963880194169360318337544673523362047845500003550655797865897637169483847774934889398916928636347805229296463546812516445182705545212838429981490065783731353925307067135133992 5 15 19 58 55 944
Alternate output: Neverending
```

And these are the stats of the PGP key:

```
Passwords: 4,505,684,579,918,576,285,346,738,866,335,056,898,110,301,685,668,199,078,230,938,179,212,682,315,156,231,410,185,391,761,603,272,976,014,035,539,665,517,248,679,228,261,440,294,129,198,036,262,705,242,310,399,830,546,082,361,923,420,737,260,766,677,891,361,176,003,624,143,368,380,527,062,643,297,677,246,518,686,688,642,023,537,863,317,793,178,302,508,440,097,154,593,959,832,175,055,427,351,149,410,096,495,695,380,712,810,868,774,475,142,767,054,868,274,802,269,522,299,482,066,464,842,097,715,922,988,138,315,118,067,288,670,934,735,264,524,936,706,249,961,394,413,647,964,221,767,703,673,264,468,419,121,528,644,906,680,808,060,759,817,669,970,046,776,525,266,199,099,671,937,918,801,013,826,958,891,378,841,908,663,991,372,649,027,188,879,525,186,690,599,345,723,173,064,252,017,258,129,131,786,488,462,307,158,861,824,049,980,863,991,149,295,162,169,512,952,373,415,599,734,988,691,348,925,488,351,712,593,858,837,027,205,238,618,188,975,201,320,681,214,515,875,812,195,250,605,867,622,987,451,763,883,339,709,733,502,125,838,221,788,546,339,051,347,360,900,518,381,976,167,289,930,943,228,024,924,785,158,428,496,314,937,921,503,359,298,542,415,845,218,449,360,806,235,379,253,546,728,753,218,950,843,742,471,105,739,555,344,908,900,309,982,913,223,331,321,839,212,821,903,239,320,600,564,890,951,140,667,647,680,682,245,252,370,183,758,578,065,733,075,207,856,432,661,797,090,351,101,165,469,273,829,754,476,555,209,675,613,232,875,323,406,611,257,057,059,099,019,633,298,079,410,970,345,108,939,943,042,100,267,260,413,671,556,828,411,902,575,269,208,445,279,433,655,878,082,023,068,697,154,581,711,817,787,688,949,105,583,339,471,599,190,831,084,304,744,483,799,555,478,063,729,574,297,623,870,804,763,558,027,580,772,927,971,329,879,231,979,556,301,616,929,595,576,646,883,067,201,999,872,899,862,889,211,861,332,535,050,455,387,251,034,043,732,447,006,164,551,883,918,733,705,027,099,846,583,024,013,092,062,384,703,436,459,115,108,358,829,136,251,317,699,709,899,140,949,893,425,335,769,021,022,912,434,045,643,544,474,460,899,799,213,759,568,795,794,758,914,390,056,283,305,470,380,859,003,818,724,678,434,816
Output: 144858686339974803412639495445442930108998896787172038266169565946909796654971431654622934722327449074525319562291578211137739886840732034401886018044055761311424449664413690224320369299057721231224396352345948448015131278860508182828147139982752631922511354755096078964028889980704480936709984283352948061204198196785328857204061945957268141550998891534834171375541476907019128991072373909056348731183618329634024763694746476776233417623704464804027405450152026906721990999895827471385353870130056140660354679074035526421905828555132520211676677361401337091034117370453939870215183392876069255694823382473711006907851853458746913295694931911314073828877816349504523255816791677974298928074750103049081088894521647398444396729546431174466495229648516324713327536964168664025148591452750098101445502202880078966283755495859954505040675103796820824907455740718188735077328268047865426806174561044520100917915500979652319301547868727504821981520811835192875926630119576922600465887060849654310721522802609638109522185755307201898676461606130734024600227278608209698963323356340446015796148617903068964091403666193996894642822309315198786075754477250953946657292049336910661279747924178751224344877465829301109562043071275369906871767991229129085786546569052197642684662087651029574035646976531236521763373563846425925268656816387911380422031991615290633773786744123323731112880994579065426763237282889858685438654794679302568796507941872848896038602862540480809810919146613018187362072374644736799940064590439265446053422181856817801562474722208358918298576208528044087753034364036 10 24 22 32 4 679
Alternate output: Neverending
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)[date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Comment: Is there any wrong information?

Comment: Please provide proper test cases, i.e. with all input parameters (speed of computer is missing) and solutions, so that we can verify our programs.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason you should should go with our defaults and allow [functions and programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/34531) . Don't allow loopholes.

Comment: IMO this challenge would be better if it allowed simply returning/outputting an integer number of milliseconds. As it is, the mixed-base conversion will be trivial for languages that have a builtin for it, and nearly as long as the code to compute the length of time (if not longer) for languages that don't.

Comment: You can see how many people agree with Mego's suggestion [in the discussion on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20283).

Comment: In response to `"It's not enforced, but strongly encouraged to write a standalone program."`: Elsewhere in the same discussion it recommends avoiding saying ["ideally your code will...](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8066/20283). That will just be ignored anyway (otherwise the code won't be competitive). Make a definite decision one way or the other rather than a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

## Ping Pong

### The Challenge

This challenge is to make a program that prints a text ping-pong animation. Your program is to display a string of tildes with a `PING` on it moving to the right. Each tick, the text `PING` moves one to the right one character, reducing the number of tildes on the right by one and increasing the amount on the left by one. Once the `PING` reaches the right side of the string, it changes to a `PONG` and the reverse happens (i.e it moves to the left instead).

### Rules

- The number of tildes must always be the same
- The number of tildes must be at least 30
- The number of milliseconds between ticks must be at least 10 ms and at most 1 s
- The `PING` must start at the left hand of the string

### Scoring

Your score is the number of bytes plus/minus the following (all that apply):

- -10 bytes for browser implementation using the ping after the hash
  [image: Example]
- +10 bytes if your implementation does not clear previously outputted frames
- More suggestions welcome

Lowest score wins.

### Example Implementation (JS, Ungolfed)

```
i=0;b=false;len=50;td=40;function urlPong(){location.hash=new Array(i+1).join("~")+(!b?"PING":"PONG")+new Array(len-4-i+1).join("~");if(!b){if(len-4-i<=0){b=true;}else{i++;}}else{if(i<=0){b=false;}else{i--;};}setTimeout(urlPong,td);}urlPong();
```

Comment: Why do you restrict this to be in a browser? That seems to add an unnecessary limitation on which languages can reasonably participate.

Comment: Okay, I made it less browser dependant

Answer (score 1):

## Implement this cipher

(I'm not sure what to call this cipher)

### Goal

Use the algorithm (explained in the Algorithm section) to implement a certain cipher.

The program must read input from STDIN or the closest available equivalent, use the algorithm to generate the ciphertext and a key.

The ciphertext and the key will be written to STDOUT or the closest available equivalent, preferably with the format `(ciphertext)\n(key)`.

### Algorithm

Convert the characters in the string into the respective ASCII values. For example:

`Hello -> 72 101 108 108 111`

Next, you will need to generate a key as long as the string with random numbers in the range of 0-9.

`Hello -> 62841`

Add the integers in the random number sequence to the ASCII values of the string. In the above examples, 72 would become 78, and 101 would become 104.

`72 + 6 = 78, 101 + 2 = 104, 108 + 8 = 116, etc`

Next, convert the new ASCII values back to characters. In the above examples, the text `Hello` has become `Nhttp`.

### Examples

(These are simply examples of what the output *might* look like. The output can and will vary.)

```
Hello, World!

Hgqqu/$\\p{ni$
0255634519253
```

---

```
This will be encoded
    
Zhjs$~koo gj$iuhofgj
60104723305544750226
```

### Rules

- Submissions must be full programs.
- Languages newer than the challenge are allowed.
- Submissions will be scored in bytes.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

---

I'm sure this challenge needs a little tidying up and making it look and sound a bit nicer. I'm not very good at writing challenges, so I'd like some advice.

Comment: This is an actual cipher (though not usually with ASCII codes). I don't remember the name right now. But seeing that, it might be a dupe.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Oh, I didn't know that. I thought it was original.

Comment: Yeah, it's called something like a key cipher.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ What do you think of this challenge? Do you have any advice for making it... better?

Comment: If properly implemented (i.e. with a pre-shared key which covers the full range of symbols rather than just 0-9) this would be a one-time pad, which is (in some sense) the limit case of the Vigenère cipher. It's not *quite* a dupe of the [Caesar cipher question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67044/194), but it's barely more complicated.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The Caesar cipher shifts the characters up the alphabet, but this one shifts the up the whole character range.

Comment: How does this handle overflow? It's easy to imagine a scenario where `z` (122) gets a number >=5 added to it.

Comment: @TimmyD I hadn't thought about that... Maybe it could display an \x code? That's what my Python implementation does, but I'm not sure if that will work in some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

## Latin vs Greek vs Cyrillic / Battle of the Alphabets

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)[classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)[pattern-recognition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-recognition)

---

**Meta:** This is just a rough draft, the challenge is still under development, feel free to add suggestions as comments or via chat pinging @flawr

Points that are unclear so far:

- Is there one fixed typeface for all three?
- Will the image always be provided in the exact horizontal orientation?
- How long will the provided text be, just single words? A single line? A multiline piece of text?

---

These three alphabets are relatively similar and even have some letters in common, but also a lot of distinct letters. In this challenge, you have to write a classifier that can distinguish these three alphabets, when presented with a raster image of a corresponding text.

This is an image from Wikipedia that shows the differences in the capital letters:

[image]

This challenge was inspired by [this message.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30367326#30367326)

Comment: What about ambiguity? Expected output for `POTATO`, `COMA`, or `TAXONOMY`?

Comment: Good point, then all outputs are correct. But I had longer pieces of texts in mind, like multiple lines, but now I'm thinking perhaps just single words would be easier. What would you say?

Comment: I'd prefer the input to be a single letter, and the correct output to list all alphabets where it belongs, with score being number of correctly classified letters in a test battery (secondary goal is byte count). That may be vulnerable to hashing tricks though. Maybe the letters could also be randomly scaled to, say, 90% to 110%?

Comment: @Zgarb it's still easy to get 100% with computer vision classifiers if there is only one nicely cropped letter as input and all test images have the same exact font as the one used in training

Comment: I agree, thats why I'd use at least full words or lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't let those functions get away

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Introduction

My imaginary language, PremOpt discourages the use of functions. They are the source of every performance problem. Your task today is to fix beginner PremOpt programmer's code.

Every statement's and loop's (if, switch, while, for) content is enclosed in brackets:

```
<if/switch/while/for> <statement here> {
    <stuff>
}
```

Switch cases are one liners:

```
switch <value> {
    case <val1>: <statement1>;
    case <val2>: <statement2>;
    case <val2>: <statement2>;
}
```

Functions look like these:

```
function <name>(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // Stuff here
}

// Calling a function:
<name>(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Other lines end with a semi-colon.

Variables don't need to be declared, they're already initialized to null, you can set a variable to a value with

```
variableName = value;
```

Outputting a value is done by doing

```
out-><value>
```

### Input

Your input is a string with a piece of code. Each row is separated with a line-feed. The input may or may not contain functions.

### Output

You need to remove the functions from the code, and put their content to the where they were called.

Examples:

```
function hello() {
    sayHello1();
    sayHello2();
}
hello();
```

becomes

```
sayHello1();
sayHello2();
```

Multiple function calls:

```
function func() {
    doStuff1();
    doStuff2();
}
func();
func();
```

becomes

```
doStuff1();
doStuff2();
doStuff1();
doStuff2();
```

If the function takes in arguments:

```
function argFunc(arg1, arg2) {
    doStuffWithArg(arg1);
    doStuffWithArg2(arg2);
}
argFunc(myVar1, myVar2);
argFunc(myVar3, myVar4);
```

then you need to change the arguments inside the function to match with the calling arguments

```
doStuffWithArg(myVar1);
doStuffWithArg2(myVar2);
doStuffWithArg(myVar3);
doStuffWithArg2(myVar4);
```

### Test cases

fibonacci sequence:

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
function getNextNumber(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

while(true) {
    a = getNextNumber(a, b);
    out->a;
    b = getNextNumber(a, b);
    out->b;
}
```

Should become

```
a = 1;
b = 1;

while(true) {
    a = a + b;
    out->a;
    b = a + b;
    out->b;
}
```

FizzBuzz:

```
for (counter = 0; counter <= 100; counter++) {
    checkNumber(counter);
}

function checkNumber(num) {
    if (num % 3 == 0  num % 5 == 0) {
        out->"Fizz Buzz";
    } else if (num % 3 == 0) {
        out->"Fizz"
    } else if (num % 5 == 0) {
        out->"Buzz"
    } else {
        out->num;
    }
    out->newLine;
}
```

Becomes:

```
for (counter = 0; counter <= 100; counter++) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0  counter % 5 == 0) {
        out->"Fizz Buzz";
    } else if (counter % 3 == 0) {
        out->"Fizz"
    } else if (counter % 5 == 0) {
        out->"Buzz"
    } else {
        out->counter;
    }
    out->newLine;
}
```

### Rules

- There'll be no recursive functions in the input
- Standard loopholes are forbidden

Comment: This grammar doesn't seem to be well defined enough for this to not be too broad. What about functions in functions? What kinds of literals are expected to be supported? Can functions have the same name but different arguments? What operators have to be supported (specifically w.r.t. functions, like `myFun(++foo)++`)? What about functions that return things but have more than one operations, but are in a heavily nested statement? This is all just from the top of my head, there are likely more such problems. I think you would need to heavily simplify the language for this to be a good question.

Answer (score 1):

### Golfing with ultrasound

Within medical physics, the percentage of ultrasound reflected between material boundaries can be calculated using two pieces of data: the density(p) and the speed(c) at which sound travels through the material.

To calculated the percentage reflection the following equation can be used

(Z1-Z2)^2 / (Z1+Z2)^2

Where Z1 and Z2 are the acoustic impedances(Z) of the two materials.
Z is calculated such that Z=pc
That is density * speed of sound in the material

### This is where the issue lies

I have two ways of asking the question

### 1:

Given the acoustic impedance for two materials, calculate the percentage reflection.

### 2:

Given the density and speed of sound in two materials, calculate the percentage reflection

### Reason

The first method will be much simpler, in the way you are just plugging values into a formula. However I feel that method 2 is heavy on the inputs, and I understand that four inputs is a large number of inputs in golfing challenges

On posting the question I will also add a number of test cases

Comment: Firstly, I think you should add test cases while it's still in the sandbox. I find it's easy to miss important ones. In your formula you say `Z=pc`. What is `c`? I think you should add some formatting to your formulas, as they are a bit hard to read. You could also consider using some TeX service to generate an image of the formula for you. Also, density is usually denoted by `ρ`.

Comment: I was going to use rho, but I didn't know where to find one. In hind sight I could have copied and pasted from Wikipedia. Speed should have been given as c not v. But I will make clear what I mean by Z=pc. What is TeX? I've not heard of it before?

Comment: TeX is a very popular typesetting program, most of your textbooks were probably made using some variant of it. For example, go to [this site](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and enter `\frac{(Z_1-Z_2)^2}{(Z_1+Z_2)^2}` as the text. You should see a much easier to read version of your formula as an image.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Wow that's a really cool website, thanks! I will edit the question soon and hopefully it will be better

Comment: With either option, it looks like there's a direct mathematical formula that leaves little to golf.

Answer (score 1):

## Write a BF to Hexagony Converter!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)[code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)[hexagonal-grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid)

---

According to community moderator [Martin Ender ♦](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender):

> Hexagony is Turing-complete as any brainfuck program can be translated to Hexagony with some effort. ([Source](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony/blob/master/README.md))

Your program's job is simple: take a valid brainfuck program, and convert it to an equivalent Hexagony program. For completeness, here are all the relavant commands in both BrainFuck and Hexaongy (taken from [esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org)).

#### brainfuck

> brainfuck operates on an array of memory cells, also referred to as the tape, each initially set to zero. There is a pointer, initially pointing to the first memory cell. The commands are:
>
> - `>` Move the pointer to the right
> - `<` Move the pointer to the left
> - `+` Increment the memory cell under the pointer
> - `-` Decrement the memory cell under the pointer
> - `.` Output the character signified by the cell at the pointer
> - `,` Input a character and store it in the cell at the pointer (-1 for EOF)
> - `[` Jump past the matching ] if the cell under the pointer is less than or equal to 0
> - `]` Jump back to the matching [ if the cell under the pointer is nonzero
>
> All characters other than ><+-.,[] should be considered comments and ignored.

#### Modifications:

- Infinite tape in both directions
- Arbitrary precision integers (like hexagony)

  - No overflow/underflow
- `[` acts the same for negative numbers as it does for 0

#### Hexagony

> #### Source code
>
> The source code consists of printable ASCII characters and line feeds and is interpreted as a pointy-topped hexagonal grid, where each cell holds a single-character command.
>
> Because of this restriction, the number of commands in the source code
>   will always be a centered hexagonal number. For reference, the first
>   10 centered hexagonal numbers are:
>
> `1, 7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127, 169, 217, 271`
>
> When reading a source file,
>   Hexagony first strips all whitespace characters. Then the remaining source
>   code is padded to the next centered hexagonal number with no-ops and
>   rearranged it into a regular hexagon. This means that the spaces in
>   the examples above were only inserted for cosmetic reasons but don't
>   have to be included in the source code. The following three programs
>   are identical:
>
> ```
>    a b c  
>   d e f g 
>  h . . . .  
>   . . . .   
>    . . . 
>
> abcdefgh...........
>
> abcdefgh
> ```
>
> But note that
>
> `abcdefg`
>
> would instead be the short form of
>
> ```
>    a b 
>   c d e  
>    f g
> ```
>
> #### Control flow
>
> Hexagony has 6 instruction pointers (IPs). They start out in the corners of the source code, pointing along the edge in the clockwise direction. Only one IP is active at any given time, initially the one in the top left corner (moving to the right). There are commands which let you switch to another IP, in which case the current IP will make another move (but not execute the next command), and then the new IP will start by executing its current command before making its first move. Each IP has an index from 0 to 5:
>
> ```
>    0 . 1
>   . . . .
>  5 . . . 2
>   . . . .
>    4 . 3
> ```
>
> The direction of an IP can be changed via several commands which resemble mirrors and branches.
>
> The edges of the hexagon wrap around to the opposite edge. In all of the following grids, if an IP starts out on the a moving towards the b, the letters will be executed in order before returning to a:
>
> ```
>    . . . .          . a . .          . . k .          . g . .   
>   a b c d e        . . b . .        . . j . .        . h . . a  
>  . . . . . .      g . . c . .      . . i . . e      . i . . b . 
> . . . . . . .    . h . . d . .    . . h . . d .    . j . . c . .
>  f g h i j k      . i . . e .      . g . . c .      k . . d . . 
>   . . . . .        . j . . f        f . . b .        . . e . .  
>    . . . .          . k . .          . . a .          . f . .
> ```
>
> If the IP leaves the grid through corner in the direction of the corner there are two possibilities:
>
> ```
> -> . . . .   
>   . . . . .  
>  . . . . . . 
> . . . . . . . ->
>  . . . . . . 
>   . . . . .  
> -> . . . .
> ```
>
> If the current memory cell (see below) is positive, the IP will continue on the bottom row. If it's zero or negative, the IP will continue on the top row. For the other 5 corners, just rotate the picture. Note that if the IP leaves the grid in a corner but doesn't point at a corner, the wrapping happens normally. This means that there are two paths that lead to each corner:
>
> ```
>       . . . . ->   
>      . . . . .  
>     . . . . . . 
> -> . . . . . . .
>     . . . . . . 
>      . . . . .  
>       . . . . ->
> ```
>
> #### Special characters
>
> `.` is a no-op: the IP will simply pass through.
>   `@` terminates the program.
>
> #### Arithmetic
>
> `)` increments the current memory edge.
>   `(` decrements the current memory edge.
>
> #### I/O
>
> `,` reads a single byte from STDIN and sets the current memory edge to its value, or -1 if EOF is reached.
>   `;` takes the current memory edge modulo 256 (positive) and writes the corresponding byte to STDOUT.
>
> ### Control flow
>
> `$` is a jump. When executed, the IP completely ignores the next command in its current direction. This is like Befunge's `#`.
>   `_, |, /, \` are mirrors. They reflect the IP in the direction you'd expect. For completeness, the following table shows how they deflect an incoming IP. The top row corresponds to the current direction of the IP, the left column to the mirror, and the table cell shows the outgoing direction of the IP:
>
> ```
>   cmd │  E SE SW  W NW NE
> ──────┼────────────────────
>    /  │ NW  W SW SE  E NE
>    \  │ SW SE  E NE NW  W
>    _  │  E NE NW  W SW SE
>    |  │  W SW SE  E NE NW
> ```
>
> `<` and `>` act as either mirrors or branches, depending on the incoming direction. The cells indicated as ?? are where they act as branches. In these cases, if the current memory edge is positive, the IP takes a 60° right turn (e.g. < turns E into SE). If the current memory edge is zero or negative, the IP takes a 60° left turn (e.g. < turns E into NE).
>
> ```
>   cmd │  E SE SW  W NW NE
> ──────┼────────────────────
>    <  │ ?? NW  W  E  W SW 
>    >  │  W  E NE ?? SE  E
> ```
>
> `[` switches to the previous IP (wrapping around from 0 to 5).
>   `]` switches to the next IP (wrapping around from 5 to 0).
>   `#` takes the current memory edge modulo 6 and switches to the IP with that index.
>
> #### Memory manipulation
>
> `{` moves the MP to the left neighbour.
>   `}` moves the MP to the right neighbour.
>   `"` moves the MP backwards and to the left. This is equivalent to =}=.
>   `'` moves the MP backwards and to the right. This is equivalent to ={=.
>   `=` reverses the direction of the MP. (This doesn't affect the current memory edge, but changes which edges are considered the left and right neighbour.)

Some commands/description omitted for conciseness, full list [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony).

### Other rules:

- Input/Output may be done however is most natural for your language

  - Output does not have to be formatted like a hexagon
- Must run in a reasonable amount of time

  - Minimal brute-force
  - No brute-forcing the entire program
- You can only use Hexagony commands specified in this challenge.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins

  - {META NOTE: I know this challenge is hard, is there a better way to score?}
- As usual, standard loopholes are prohibited.

### Test Cases:

```
Input: (cat)

,.[,.]

Output: (example)

   \ . .
  < _ . .
 . _ ; . .
  . . > ,
   . @ .

Input: ("123")

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+.

Output: (example)

     ) ) ) ) )
    ) ) ; ) ; /
   ) ) ) ) ) ) /
  ) ) ) ) ) ) ) /
 ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) /
  ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
   ) ) ) ) ) ) )
    ) ) ) ) ) )
     . . @ ; <

Input: (@primo's infinite Fibonacci)

+[[<+>->+>+<<]>]

Output: (example)

       ) \ . . . . |
      . | . / { } < .
     . . . . > [ . / >
    . . . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . @ . . . .
  / . ] < . > < . ] . . .
 _ > " ' / | . > < . . . .
  _ / . . . / . . [ . . .
   . / . . . . . . ) . .
    . . . . . . . . ] .
     . . . [ . . . . |
      . . [ . . . . (
       . \ ) ] ) ] <
```

Comment: I am quite sure that the outputs are not unique, are they?

Comment: @flawr The outputs do not have to be unique as long as the inputted BF programs do the exact same thing, under all circumstances.

Comment: I think Hexagony's padding rules would be important, especially if you don't require the output to be formatted like a hexagon. I predict most answers to generate tons of no-ops at the end, which can't be omitted without messing up the layout.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mask brainfuck in the question body, since it hurts searchability. You're going to need the brainfuck tag anyway.

Comment: @Dennis Should I change the title as well?

Comment: No, the title cannot contain *fuck* due to network-wide rules.

Comment: I think this challenge is actually rather easy except for translating `[]` loops: everything else is a simple mapping. I think the most likely type of answer will just generate the code mostly linearly while keeping track of a "stack" of loops and then figuring out what size hexagon to put it in.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Should I make this challenge metagolf to encourage less linear output?

Comment: @Blue That would certainly be interesting, but I have doubts you'd get a lot of participation in that case.

Comment: I agree with Martin, I may not have worded my last comment very well, as the `[]` translations will actually be rather time consuming, if not difficult. Further increasing the complexity of the challenge will make it more interesting, but it might be too much to expect more than an answer or two at that point.

Answer (score 1):

### Platformer game

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Write a platformer game.

Rules:

- Keyboard input, minimum three commands: left, right and jump;
- Real-time. Screen should update (and the game iterate) on timer. Update speed should not depend on CPU speed. FPS should be between 2 and 120;
- It should be possible both to win and to lose (the game can although be very hard and require preparing a special bot to win or to lose);
- Playing field should have at lest 64 positions, minimum width is 6, minimum height is 5.
- Player may move left, right or jump. Player moves down automatically unless on a platform. Jumping means moving up for some limited time (not higher than 67% of playing field's height), then falling down like usual.
- Falling down outside playing field is losing the game. Stepping on 6 distinct platforms is a win.
- Player, platforms and borders of area should be visible on playing field. If output method is ASCII art, it may looks like this:

  ```
  .....----...
  ............
  ...@....----
  ..---.......
  .......---..
  ............
  ```
- Platforms may be horizontal, vertical, diagonal. Platforms should not overlap (except of differently oriented). Platform's projection to horizontal and vertical axes should not overlap for at least 4 platforms. Example of too projection-overlapping playing field:

  ```
  ............
  ....@.......
  .--.--..--..
  ............
  .--.--..--..
  ............
  ```
- Platforms may move. Overlapping rules apply only to initial positions.
- The game should track losing and winning conditions and stop the game, outputting distinct messages in case of lose or win.

Comment: I feel like this spec is much too broad. Different answers will vary so much that I don't think they will be comparable. I think you need to specify each interaction precisely.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, The idea was to just implement a platformer game, with rules only to prevent "degenerate", uninteresting cases (like 1x1 field with 0 platforms and unconditional lose in the first turn). Do you think it would be more interesting if each answer's game would basically be the same?

Comment: I think it is a much more interesting golfing problem if all the games are the same, as otherwise what is the point of golfing? I don't think this is a good site to try to get interesting platforming games, as I don't think this will work with either a pop-con or code-challenge either.

Comment: I though it would be interesting if main point were to design the game to be compactly implementable, not just to implement already designed game in a compact way...

Answer (score 1):

## Compute h-index of PPCG users

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

*Thanks to @Suever for his help refining this challenge.*

### Background

The [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) is a commonly used metric that measures the amount and quality of publications of a given scholar or researcher. It is defined as follows:

> A scholar with an h-index of *n* has published *n* papers each of which has been cited at least *n* times.

### Adaptation for PPCG

In this challenge I propose to compute the h-index of PPCG users based on the analogy

- **paper** → **answer**;
- paper's **citations** → answer's **vote count**, defined as upvotes minus downvotes.

The following examples illustrate the computation of h-index. The array to the left is the vote count of answers in descending order for a hypothetical user, and the number to the right is the resulting h-index:

```
[5 3 2 1 1]    2
[1 1 1]        1
[]             0
[-1 -2]        0
[0]            0
[9 4 3 ...]    3
```

Referring to the last example, note that we don't need to know the array entries after the `3`.

### The challenge

Given a user identification, **output their h-index**.

### Rules

**User identification** can be defined as anything reasonable, such as user number, user name, or user name without spaces.

The result must be based on **actual data** from the PPCG site. You may want to take a look at the StackExchange API, for example [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users).

Note that some users have a lot of answers. For one such user the API may not give all the results, or may only give them split across several chunks. However, if you ask the API to provide the results **with an appropriate sorting** you may not need all of them to compute the h-index (see last example above). Also, you may assume that the h-index of any user will be **less than 100**.

If the answer can't be tested in an online compiler (for example due to restrictions to read web content), you are encouraged (although not required) to post some **evidence** that the answer works, such as a screen capture.

This is code golf. Fewest bytes wins.

### Table of h-indices

After submitting your answer, you may optionally **edit the table** below to include your own h-index, in the indicated format. Please keep the table in **decreasing order**, so that users with higher h-indices appear higher on the table. I will remove the dummy user names when the table has some actual content.

```
Example user name: 5
Another example: 3
Yet another user: 3
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Having 1000 answers is irrelevant _only if_ you ask the API for the answers in _descending order_ of votes. The note is intended to make it clear that asking for the answers in that order is probably a good idea. I've rephrased a little, I hope it's clearer now. As for how many results the API provides in the same chunk, I think the limit is 100, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes,  I think that is much clearer now. Also, _Yet another user_? I hate that guy...

Comment: We've had a challenge to find the [h index](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42661/20260). With that done, this mostly looks like a question to query the SE API.

Comment: @xnor Oh. Pity. I didn't see that challenge. I guess this is mostly a duplicate then

Answer (score 1):

## What  is closer?

Tags: [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math),[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Inputs: a, b (Both integer and positive)
.Output: Integer, in natural numbers sequence.

We have one single atom which has `a` electrons, we ionize the atom with `b` positive charges (take `b` electrons out).

The output is the sum of the orbital quantum numbers (n,l,ml) which is nearest to the atom shell.

EXAMPLE: We take 3 electrons from <sub>26</sub>Fe, Now we have <sub>26</sub>Fe<sup>3+</sup>. We need to get the sum of the nearest remained orbitals quantum numbers to the shell.

We have this configuration for Fe<sup>3+</sup>: [Ar], 3d<sup>3</sup>, 4s<sup>2</sup>

The nearest orbital to shell has these numbers:

```
n = 4
l = 0
ml = 0
```

In this case:

```
a => 26
b => 3
output => 4
```

---

My 3rd grade chemistry teacher asked me once to create such a program, but I didn't success, I found the paper that my teacher wrote these descriptions on it and I typed it here because I believe that someone might create an interesting code-golf for this.

Comment: You can't create the [tag:atoms] and [tag:electrons] tags right now (2/150 rep). Even then, we're not going to need them.

Comment: This is a long way from being self-contained. I don't know whether someone who knows quantum chemistry would find the question clear, but I need a link to some background material to even start trying to work out what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## KotH Chess Warriors.

This game will be based on fairy chess, but really could be imagined to be anything else.

Submissions will include both: A function that determines the moves of the piece (as in, how the piece can move), called at the start, and a function that determines how it moves each turn, called each turn, of course. Bot's move simultaneously; strategy is needed. A piece may make 5 moves in a row before it must rest.

Bot's will be able to do any valid move they choose, and the input they will get when deciding what to do will be: a value that can be 2, 1, 0, or -1, for each possible move. 2 denotes that an ally is in that square, 1 denotes that an enemy is in that space. 0 denotes an empty space which could be moved to, -1 represents an illegal move, which may result from the board ending or another piece in the way. If a piece attempts to move into it's ally, the following things could happen; A) ally stays still; Piece stays where it is. B) ally moves; Piece moves where it wishes. C) ally is captured; Piece recaptures

See below for early stage point spending system

### Sandbox

I don't have the experience to host this challenge, so someone who can program these kind of things will need to help.

I have sketched out some movement point system, but I need to figure out how large the board is, and so how valuable riders (pieces that move continously, like a rook), would be, compared to leapers, before i could finalise it

Here is the quick system done, which could clearly be improved (for one thing, the multiple move thing probably needs to be a bit more expensive):

---

#### Point buying system

Points: each piece receives (to be decided) points
base move: points spent on a move are as so. Largest dimension + floor(small dimension/2).
There are no riders in this mode; Only repeated movement
Repeated movement by x cost:*ceil(x^1.25)
make move-only=/2
It is possible to have a leaping attack and sliding attack on the same square; it is also possible to have only one of these able to attack; How this is sorted is that both moves get their own value, and so you can attack if the attack move by itself can reach there.

Examples for base move costs:

- Any king move: 1
- any knight move: 2
- Zebra move:4
- Camel move:3

PLEASE NOTE: These move values on their own are not representative of how powerful a piece with that move actually is; A knight is better than a camel or zebra. However, when paired with other moves, the zebra and camel moves may become effective.

Example of moves that can be purchased:

```
     1
7   2  3
6    @55555
     4
```

- move 1=(2+floor(0/2)):2 points
- move 2=(1+floor(1/2)):1 point
- move 3=(2+floor(1/2)):2 points
- move 4=(1+floor(0/2)): 1 point
- move 5=((1+floor(0/2))*ceil(5^1.25))=8 points
- move 6=(5+floor(0/2))=5 points
- move 7=(5+floor(1/2))=5 points

in total, this piece costs: (2+2+1+1+8+5+5) 24 points.

---

Considerations:

- How large the board is. I'm fairly sure of having a cylindrical board; the left wraps to the right and vice versa.
- how exactly turns work. So far, I have thought that the way it works is this:
  Everyone moves simultaneously. When you move, you deplete your remaining moves, which tops and starts at 5. You can choose to not move, and replenish your moves at any point.

  However, this could induce stale games which don't end properly.

Comment: I think you should add a hyperlink to the Wikipedia page on Fairy Chess for users to refer to. Also, if you're interested, there's a great game online that involves unique fairy chess pieces. It's called [Chess Evolved Online](http://www.kongregate.com/games/thegrandestine/chess-evolved-online). Not only are there different pieces, but you build your setup ahead of time and don't know what setup your opponent will have.

Answer (score 1):

### Calculate my total hours

I record the work I do for one of my customers using a flat file in the following format:

```
0000-00-00 0000-0000 0.0 code0000 free text
```

The `0.0` represents the amount of time spent on the task identified by `code0000`, where `0000` is an optional numeric task ID and `code` is a project code (and does not contain digits or spaces).

Because I'm lazy, I need as short a program as possible to calculate subtotals of my total time for each project, plus a grand total. If you are using plain text output it should show the hours first and then the project code on the same line, and then the grand total on a line on its own with no code. You don't need to use a specific numeric format but you should be capable of dealing with half hours (0.5) in both the input and output.

Comment: Are the beginning strings (presumably a date, and something else?) and the free text ever relevant? If not, I'd consider omitting them. Is any order for the subtotals acceptable?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Sorry, but that's my actual input format. The good news is that the subtotals can be in any order.

Comment: It's obviously up to you, but I think that input makes it a chameleon challenge. I wrote a preliminary Pyth answer to do this, and only 16 of the 36 bytes were related to summing and grouping, the other 20 were used for processing. (Surely it can't be that hard to preprocess away the first two fields and the free text? :P )

Comment: If I didn't have to preprocess them away I could just open the file in Excel and be done with it...

Answer (score 1):

## Undone Mathematics

### Definitions

I define the following:

***n*ᵗʰ Undone Addition of *A***

Let *ⁿ*+ᵣ *A* denotes the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Addition of *A*; the sum of the elements of *A* after *n* layers have been removed in every dimension:

```
 ²+ᵣ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] = ∑ [3,4,5] = 12    // 1D: remove leading and trailing elements

     [[1,1,3]
 ¹+ᵣ  [4,2,5]  = ∑ [2] = 2    // 2D: remove leading and trailing rows and columns
      [3,4,1]]
```

Then *ⁿ*+ᵤ *A* denotes the *n*ᵗʰ Undone Addition of *A*; the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Addition of *A* plus the sum of the elements of *A*:

```
 ²+ᵤ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] = ²+ᵣ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] + ∑ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

     [[1,1,3]        [[1,1,3]      [[1,1,3] 
 ¹+ᵤ  [4,2,5]  = ¹+ᵣ  [4,2,5]  + ∑  [4,2,5]
      [3,4,1]]        [3,4,1]]      [3,4,1]]
```

***n*ᵗʰ Undone Multiplication of *A***

Let *ⁿ*×ᵣ *A* denotes the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Multiplication of *A*; the product of the elements of *A* after *n* layers have been removed in every dimension:

```
 ³×ᵣ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] = ∏ [1,2] = 2    // 1D: remove leading and trailing elements
```

Then *ⁿ*+ᵤ *A* denotes the *n*ᵗʰ Undone Multiplication of *A*; the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Multiplication of *A* times the product of the elements of *A*:

```
 ³×ᵤ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] = ³×ᵣ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] × ∏ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1]
```

***n*ᵗʰ Undone Average of *A***

Let μ denote the average (arithmetic mean), i.e. μ*A* = <sup>(∑*A*)</sup>⁄<sub>N</sub> and *ⁿ*μᵣ*A* denote the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Average of *A*; the average of the elements of *A* after *n* layers have been removed in every dimension:

```
 ³μᵣ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] = μ [1,2] = 1.5
```

Then *ⁿ*μᵤ *A* denotes the average of the *n*ᵗʰ Redacted Average of *A* and the average of the elements of *A*:

```
                          ³μᵣ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] + μ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1]  
 ³μᵤ [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1] = ─────────────────────────────────────────────
                                               2
```

### Task

With all this in mind, create an interpreter that will evaluate expressions that use the below operations (numbers are just examples). Alternatively, extend the language of your choice to include the notation.

```
1 + 2        Addition
3 × 4        Multiplication
μ [5,6]      Average
7 +u [8,9]   Undone Addition
9 ×u [1,2]   Undone Multiplication
2 μu [3,4]   Undone Average
```

Note that you do not need to implement redacted operations. They were only defined above to facilitate the definitions of the undone operations.

You may substitute any ASCII or Unicode symbol for `+`, `×`, and `μ` as long as you stay consistent: You may not choose `*` with `×u`.

Each undone operator has a higher order precedence than their normal counterpart.

### Test cases:

`2+u [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` → `40`

`1+u [[1,1,3][4,2,5][3,4,1]]` → `26`

`3×u [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1]` → `72`

`3μu [3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1]` → `1.625`

`0.1 × 2+u [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` → `4`

`2+u [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] × 0.1` → `4`

`0+u [[[1,1][3,2]][[1,3][3,1]]]` → `15`

`1+u [[[0,1,1][2,1,1][1,0,0]][[2,2,2][2,2,0][1,0,2]][[1,2,0][2,1,1][2,1,2]]]` → `34`

`1×u [[[1,1,2][1,1,1][1,2,1]][[1,2,2][2,2,1][2,2,1]][[1,1,1][1,1,2][2,1,1]]]` → `2048`

`1μu [[[2,2,3][3,2,1][3,3,3]][[1,3,3][2,1,1][2,1,3]][[2,3,3][3,2,3][3,2,1]]]` → `3.259`

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

Comment: I find the structure of the definitions very confusing. It would help to a) define terms before you use them; and b) be explicit about the domain and range of the operators. I also, possibly as a result of b), fail to understand the examples: ITSM that `²+ᵣ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` should be a sum over zero elements because by the time you've removed the first two rows and the last two rows you're left with -3 rows. And the test cases are even more confusing: what is `[[1,1][3,2]][[1,3][3,1]]`? It looks like two matrices side by side, but I didn't see any mention of implicit operators.

Comment: @PeterTaylor a) I originally had redacteds before undones, but I wanted to put the focus on the undones. I'll swap again. b) Notice that the input can be n-dimensional, so as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` is one-dimensional, only the first and last elements in that only dimension need to be stripped off, giving `[3,4,5]`. The later examples are missing outer brackets, to indicate that they are 3D. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: 1. There's no way visually to distinguish the 1D examples from the 2D ones. Now that you've added some `[]` to the test cases, they're better. Why not do the same for the 2D examples: add a `[` before the first row and a `]` after the last one, as a cue to distinguish them from the 1D cases? 2. If you think that the redacted distract from the undones, you could rephrase undone addition in terms of a convolution with an n-dimensional "matrix" with elements 1 or 2 according to distance from the exterior; then introduce redacted addition as an alternative way of understanding it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. is done. I'm not sure how to formulate 2).

Answer (score 1):

## Family Tree, Folder Tree

Given a simple family tree in a format reasonably similar to the format outlined below, create a file tree to match it, as explained below.

**Input**

An ascii family tree in a similar format to the following:

```
                Grandpa Jim = Grandma Jane
                            |
                 -------------------------------------------------------
                 |          |          |                               |
               Bill Bob     Jim Jane   Sam Sammyson = Aunt Jimbo     Daddy McDad = Mommy McMom
                                                    |                            |
                                                  -----------                    Me
                                                  |         |
                                                Cousin One  Cousin Two
```

The scheme can be changed within reason, however the test cases provided will meet the following specs:

1. `=` Symbolizes a marriage
2. If there are any children from a marriage, there will be a `|` one line below the `=` symbolizing the marriage.
3. A `-` character that is below a `|`, or connected (by adjacency) to a `-` that is immediately below a `|`  are used to signify multiple children. Below any of these `-` there may be a `|`, which will have a the first word of a name immediately below it. This full name is the name of a child.
4. The initial line of the family tree will only contain two people.

*This spec maybe should be cleaned up more*.

Note that there won't be any relationships more complicated than `=` marriage or `|` child linking two names. This means that more complicated relationships, such as divorce or step-children, will not appear in the tree.

**Output**

There will be no output as such, instead the program/function will create a directory structure matching the input. For example, the above example would lead to the following directory tree:

```
$ tree family_tree/
family_tree/
├── Grandma Jane
│   ├── children
│   │   ├── Bill Bob
│   │   │   └── parents
│   │   │       ├── Grandma Jane -> ../../../../Grandma Jane/
│   │   │       └── Grandpa Jim -> ../../../../Grandpa Jim/
│   │   ├── Daddy McDad
│   │   │   ├── children
│   │   │   │   └── Me
│   │   │   ├── parents -> ../Jim Jane/parents
│   │   │   └── spouse
│   │   │       └── Mommy McMom
│   │   │           ├── children -> ../../children/
│   │   │           └── spouse
│   │   │               └── Daddy McDad -> ../../../../Daddy McDad/
│   │   ├── Jim Jane
│   │   │   └── parents -> ../Bill Bob/parents/
│   │   └── Sam Sammyson
│   │       ├── children
│   │       │   ├── Cousin One
│   │       │   └── Cousin Two
│   │       ├── parents -> ../Jim Jane/parents
│   │       └── spouse
│   │           └── Aunt Jimbo
│   │               ├── children -> ../../children/
│   │               └── spouse
│   │                   └── Sam Sammyson -> ../../../../Sam Sammyson/
│   └── spouse
│       └── Grandpa Jim -> ../../Grandpa Jim/
└── Grandpa Jim
    ├── children -> ../Grandma Jane/children/
    └── spouse
        └── Grandma Jane -> ../Grandma Jane/
```

The directory tree must satisfy the following:

1. Create a directory called `family_tree` that will contain the entire family tree.
2. Inside `family_tree/` there will be exactly two directories, these are the two people at the top of the family tree.
3. For every person in the tree, do the following in their directory:

   1. If they have a spouse, create a `spouse` directory. If the spouse already has a directory named after them, create a link to that directory within the  `spouse` directory. Otherwise, create a directory in the `spouse` directory with the name of the spouse.
   2. If they have children, then they must have a spouse. If the spouse already has a directory named `children`, then create a link to that directory and name the link `children`. If their spouse doesn't already have this directory, create the `children` directory and add a directory corresponding to each child.

*Again, this is a rough draft. The spec needs to be cleaned. I welcome comments*

Note that, in all cases, it does not matter where the true directory and where the link is, as long as the link is properly setup. Also, it is okay to create links to other links.

Also, *link* means *symbolic link* throughout the challenge.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 1):

## The French Farmer in the Dell

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

I used to work with kids and [The Farmer in the Dell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Farmer_in_the_Dell) was a popular song among them. Also, I like challenge like [99 bottles of beer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64198/15214) or [Polar Bear, Polar Bear, what do you hear?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85746/15214). Try them too!

### Goal

In your programming language of choice, write the smallest program possible which will output the following text. Output should match exactly, including case, spacing, and punctuation. A trailing linefeed is fine but specify it in your answer. We will play with the [french version](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Fermier_dans_son_pr%C3%A9) of the song because I find it more interesting than the english version (also I am french so more memories for me!).

```
Le fermier dans son pre,
Le fermier dans son pre,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
Le fermier dans son pre.

Le fermier prend sa femme,
Le fermier prend sa femme,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
Le fermier prend sa femme.

La femme prend son enfant,
La femme prend son enfant,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
La femme prend son enfant.

L'enfant prend sa nourrice,
L'enfant prend sa nourrice,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
L'enfant prend sa nourrice.

La nourrice prend son chat,
La nourrice prend son chat,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
La nourrice prend son chat.

Le chat prend sa souris,
Le chat prend sa souris,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
Le chat prend sa souris.

La souris prend son fromage,
La souris prend son fromage,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
La souris prend son fromage.

Le fromage est battu,
Le fromage est battu,
Ohe, Ohe, Ohe,
Le fromage est battu.
```

If you are french, you may note that I replace all `é` with `e`. It is not important for the challenge and I prefer to stay full ASCII.

If you want to code while listening to the song, you can find it on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/l2UXqfi7Rqg). :)

### Sandbox Questions

A not so difficult challenge. I originally thought about posting it directly, but I prefer to share it first. I don't think test case are needed. I implemented both the english and french version and the last one is far better to my taste :)

Comment: The only thing I'd be worried about is if this is a duplicate of something. If the structure of the song is too similar to another one I think it should be closed. That said, this is pretty similar to the polar bear song, but without a second verse type and with an exception or two? I don't know whether that is enough, so I wouldn't vote to close on my own.

Comment: This looks vulnerable to the techniques which have been used on previous songs, the canonical example of which is the rickroll.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix Pokemon Go's Servers [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

### Background

As you may or may not be aware, Pokemon Go's servers have not fared well under the stress of the game's extreme popularity. As an amateur programmer, I'm in the sweet spot where I know just enough to *think* I can solve all of their problems, but not enough to be able to understand how complex their problems actually are. Thus, I find myself constantly thinking "Why didn't they just do <insert naive suggestion here>? It would fix everything!" This challenge is focused on one of those probably-useless ideas I've thought up.

First, some very quick background, in case you haven't played the game (you can skip this paragraph if you have): In the course of gameplay, Pokemon can randomly appear at certain real-life locations. Every player in the same location sees the same Pokemon, and multiple players can catch one Pokemon.

One potential difficulty I see with this is storing all of that data. With millions of concurrent players, the game servers have to keep track of millions of Pokemon. That's a lot of IO for their database. Fortunately, I, a graduate of not one, but **two** introductory CS courses, have a solution! Because player interactions have nothing to do with where and when Pokemon spawn, it is essentially deterministic. This means that it should be possible to drop the database entirely (at least for this one specific task), and replace it with a function! This function could take the player's location, the current system time, and a random seed as input, and return a list of all Pokemon within a certain radius. Because no database lookup is needed, this function would be lightning fast and easily scalable to millions of players.

### The Challenge

Your challenge is to write this function. Obviously, the actual game of Pokemon has way too many details to make a feasible code challenge for PPCG, so here's the simplified guidelines:

- Create a function that takes the following inputs, in any format you like:

  - Player location, as 2D coordinates
  - System time
  - Random seed
- The function should return a list of nearby Pokemon, with the following requirements:

  - "Nearby" means "within one unit of distance of the player", where distance is 2d euclidean distance. (Just ignore the edge case where the location is on a round planet)
  - Each Pokemon should have a species and an exact location
  - This list can be in any format you want
  - The results are deterministic (i.e., for the same location, time, and random seed, the same Pokemon are always returned)
  - The Pokemon should persist for some pseudorandom amount of time

    - Thus, if the function is called twice with the same location and random seed, and two times that are very close, then each Pokemon returned the first time should have a large possibility of being returned the second time
  - If the function is called twice with the same time and random seed, and two nearby locations, then any Pokemon that are near both locations should be returned both times
  - The Pokemon should be somewhat evenly distributed across the "world" (the coordinate plane).

    - The Pokemon should be distributed such that at any location and time, the probability of finding exactly `n` nearby Pokemon of any type is `(0.5)^(n+1)`
    - Thus, there is a 50% chance of finding no Pokemon at all, a 25% chance of finding exactly 1, a 12.5% chance of finding exactly two, etc.
    - Your algorithm should be capable of returning up to 10 nearby Pokemon, but is allowed to return more, as long as it follows the right probability distribution
- Sandbox question: I want a requirement to be that the algorithm can't simply generate all of the Pokemon in the world and then just return the nearby ones, but I don't know how to formally state this. I had some fleeting thoughts about O(1) memory usage, but that method could strictly speaking have O(1) memory usage if the world is a constant size (which I'm pretty sure it is).

Might this make a good [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge? That would fit in with the premise, and might produce some interesting algorithms.

For the sake of making this challenge somewhat reasonable, the list of possible Pokemon and their probabilities of appearing will be small:

- Weedle: 60%
- Charmander: 30%
- Blastoise: 10%

### Scoring

This is part of what I need help with in the sandbox. How should I distinguish two entries that both meet all of the requirements?

---

Thanks for reading this far! I know this question isn't nearly ready to be a real challenge. At the very least, it need more specific requirements. But I figured I'd post what I currently have in the sandbox to see if it's worth continuing with. I've never posted or participated in a PPCG challenge before, and I'm sure that's obvious, but hopefully with your help, I can refine this to the point of being a legitimate challenge.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and thanks for using the sandbox! :) Currently I'm afraid your question is rather underspecified. You need to define "nearby" as well as describe how Pokemon should be distributed, as otherwise I could just put 6 weedles, 3 charmanders and a blastoise on the north pole for some time, then swap them to the south pole, etc. You could put a time constraint on the code to try to limit the whole world generation problem, but to do that you'd probably need a reference implementation. Personally, I think [tag:code-golf] is likely the best scoring method.

Comment: I was imagining this challenge would be very difficult and require a somewhat complex answer, which is why I didn't initially tag it as code golf. But after thinking about it for a little while, I came up with a rather simple solution that isn't as interesting as I thought it would be. So maybe code golf is a better tag. As for you other remarks, I'll get to work editing the answer to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: 1. Does "*the usual euclidean distance*" mean in the 3D embedding of the globe whose surface is parameterised by the input coordinates? Or have you decided to simplify by ignoring the fact that real Pokémon Go takes place on a round planet? 2. What does "*as long as it follows the right probability distribution*" mean if you curtail the probability distribution? What happens to the probability from the tail?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I have answered both of your questions by editing my post. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

## Punch Buggy Probabilities

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A popular game among children in the USA is "punch buggy", and as with every such game, there are many variations. The one we'll consider for this challenge goes like this:

- The moment anyone sees a [Volkswagon Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Beetle) (the "buggy"), participants may punch each other (*usually* in the shoulder or upper arm).
- A punch must be accompanied by "punch buggy <color>!", where <color> is the color of the VW Beetle (red, green, black, gray, yellow, etc.).
- Whoever makes contact first gets priority (and for this challenge, there are no ties).
- Once person A punches person B, B cannot punch A back (usually accomplished by saying "no punch back!").
- Punches may occur between any pair of participants (for this challenge, *every* pair of participants).

### The challenge

Assuming all possible punching configurations among `n` people are equally likely to happen, what is the probability of any particular punching configuration? To put it another way, for each *distinct* punching configuration, how many ways can it occur?

### Rules

- Input is a single positive integer greater than 1.
- Output must be one of the following: A) a list of decimals, B) a list of fractions (simplified or not), or C) a list of counts. **META:** Should I allow these lists to be unordered, or should I require that they be associated with punching configurations somehow? I'm leaning towards the former since it seems like it'd be a headache to figure out how to specify the latter *and* it would likely be an extra task that doesn't really have anything to do with the core problem.
- Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, and standard loopholes are banned.

### Test cases

```
Input
Output A
Output B
Output C

2
1.0
2/2
2

3
0.75 0.25
3/4 1/4
3 1
```

**Explanation of input 2:** With only two people, there are exactly two possible ways: either A punches B or B punches A. These are equivalent, so the probability is 1.0, the fraction is 2/2, and the count is 2.

**Explanation of input 3:** There are two distinct punching configurations: A -> B -> C, A -> C; A -> B -> C -> A. The latter has only two varieties (the other is A -> C -> B -> A) and the former has six, since there are three choices for the person who punches two others and then two choices for the remaining pair. Thus, the probabilities are 0.75 and 0.25, the fractions are 3/4 and 1/4, and the counts are 3 and 1.

### META

- I want to add `4` to the test cases, and I think I'm gonna need help on it since I'm having a hard time counting all 2^6 = 64 possibilities correctly.
- Any clarifications/corrections?

Answer (score 1):

## Teh Scrolling Codez

In many movies, computer often appear to be scrolling through some code. We should automate this process to make it easier. Your job is to write code that displays to a graphical console a scrolling view of its own source code. You have two options...

---

#### You may horizontally scroll the source as HTML's Marquee.

#### You also may vertically scroll through the source as if the source is code is on a cylinder, and only a fixed number of lines can be displayed

---

### Sandbox Questions

Should this be a code golf or pop-con. Pop-con's could result in more visually pleasing solutions.
[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [tag:popularity contest]

Comment: I'm wondering how you vertically scroll source code that's one line.

Comment: SIngle line source code is permitted. That is why it may make more sense to scroll it horizontally @feersum

Comment: A quine in a loop and rely on the console having finite height?

Comment: Yeah that could work

Comment: @PeterTaylor ^^

Comment: @PeterTaylor do you have an opinion on what tag should be used?

Comment: I suspect that [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/194) applies and that it's not an interesting question, although I personally don't find quines interesting so I'm not the best person to comment on that.

Comment: but F() in and of itself is an interesting challenge. @PeterTaylor

Comment: `F(P)` is `while(true) print P`. That's not an interesting challenge in any language I know.

Comment: @PeterTaylor than I think I should ban console output, and require graphical output

Comment: thus F(P) becomes while(true){print(sectionOf(p))move(p)};

Answer (score 1):

[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

## Autonomous Vehicle

I need a brain for my self-driving car. Something that will take still frames from the front-facing camera and give the navigation system commands. Obviously, if my car is driving me somewhere, I don't want to stop. However, I also don't want to:

1. Kill someone
2. Die

Knowing myself, we can assume that:

- At the speed I drive, [hitting the curb](https://what-if.xkcd.com/61/) or otherwise leaving the road will kill me and thus violate **Don't #2**
- With my luck, running a stop light, will violate **Don't #1** or **#2** or both
- Also hitting a pedestrian (or another car) violates **Don't #1** (and possibly **#2**)

### Input

The program/function should take an image as input. How it does this is flexible.

### Output

The program/function should output one of these commands; ideally, one of the commands that doesn't result in one of the **Don'ts** being violated.

```
╔═════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Command │ Navigational Outcome                          ║
╠═════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Forward │ No course correction, continue straight ahead ║
╟─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Left    │ Veer left                                     ║
╟─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Right   │ Veer right                                    ║
╟─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Stop    │ Screech to a grinding halt                    ║
╚═════════╧═══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

### Specifications

- Take an image as input in someway
- Output a command [ **Forward**, **Left**, **Right**, **Stop** ]

  - Commands can be aliased as [ **0**, **1**, **2**, **3** ] respectively
  - Returning one valid command and no invalid commands is sufficient to pass a test
  - **Stop** is only valid iff every other command would violate one of the **Don'ts**
- Rules for valid commands:

  - No running stop lights
  - No running over people
  - No running into vehicles
  - No running off the road
  - If a command does not violate any of the above, then it is valid
- Program/Function must be deterministic

## Scoring

Lowest score wins! The scoring function is:

- `( # of Bytes ) / ( Number of Passed Tests )`

For example, a **450 byte** Python solution that passes **2** test cases earns a score of `450 / 2` or **225**.

---

### Test Cases

1. Valid Commands: **Forward**
   [image]
2. Valid Commands: **Left**, **Right**

   - Straight ahead there are pedestrians crossing

[image]

3. Valid Commands: **Forward**, **Right**
   [image]
4. Valid Commands: **Forward**
   [image]
5. Valid Commands: **Left**, **Right**
   [image]
6. Valid Commands: **Stop**
   [image]

Comment: I like this challenge.  However, I don't see any test cases for lights.  I also think that the test case for pedestrians is pretty bad.  Also, realize that people might be using the text on the images (the road labels) to determine orientation, so make sure you're ok with that.  I'd also recommend more test cases.  Your current set is a good example set, but not comprehensive enough for testing IMO.

Comment: will all testcases be available? if so i would determine the output by the value of the pixel in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

### Embed a graph into the Rado graph

The Rado graph is an infinite undirected graph whose vertices are labelled with natural numbers `{0, 1, 2, ...}`.

The edge `(i,j)` with `i<j` is in the graph whenever the binary expansion of `j` has a `1` in its `i`th place. Here, place values are counted from the end, with the `0`'th place being the least significant bit. In terms of bitshifts, this means `(j>>i)&1==1`.

[image]

The Rado graph is [universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_graph) in that any finite graph is a [subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph) of it. This means that any finite graph can be embedded in the Rado graph: to each vertex of the finite graph, assign a distinct vertex of the Rado graph so that any two vertices of the original graph have an edge if and only if the corresponding vertices of the Rado graph have an edge.

Your task is to output such an embedding for a finite graph given as input.

TODO: Lots of stuff

Comment: Lovely challenge :). Is there a known algorithm to find the embedding? If so, might it be worth linking to it with a spoiler warning?

Comment: 1. It would be more accurate to say that this is one of several constructions of the Rado graph, and to state that answers are required to work with this construction in particular. 2. The statement of universality is incorrect. It should say [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) rather than subgraph. 3. I assume that by "*an embedding*" you mean a mapping from vertices of the input graph to vertices of this construction of the Rado graph, but it would be good to make that explicit. 4. @MartinEnder, there's a greedy algorithm described in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

## Draw Concentric Squarephabets

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmongrov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmongrov-complexity) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

### Challenge

Write a program or function that, given an input integer `n`, outputs a concentric squarephabet of size `n×n`.

A *concentric squarephabet* is an ASCII-art square of concentric rings, where the outside ring of characters are `A`s, the second `B`s, the third `C`s, etc. For example, a 25×25 squarephabet looks like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

(and yes I typed that by hand ☺)

If the input is an even number, the centre of the squarephabet will be a 2×2 square instead of a single letter. For example, for input `8`:

```
AAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBA
ABCCCCBA
ABCDDCBA
ABCDDCBA
ABCCCCBA
ABBBBBBA
AAAAAAAA
```

### Specification

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- The input to your program or function will never be less than 1 or greater than 52 (26×2). This means you do not have to deal with letters after `Z`.
- You may output uppercase or lowercase letters, but you must be consistent in your choice.

### Test Cases

Format:

```
Input
Output
```

Test cases:

```
1
A

2
AA
AA

3
AAA
ABA
AAA

10
AAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBBA
ABCCCCCCBA
ABCDDDDCBA
ABCDEEDCBA
ABCDEEDCBA
ABCDDDDCBA
ABCCCCCCBA
ABBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAA

25
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

52
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUUUUUUUUUUUUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVVVVVVVVVVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWWWWWWWWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXXXXXXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYYYYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYYYYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXXXXXXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWWWWWWWWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVVVVVVVVVVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUUUUUUUUUUUUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFEDCBA
ABCDEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEDCBA
ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEDCBA
ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCBA
ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBA
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins. Good luck!

Comment: We're getting *slightly* into idea-milking territory here. While this isn't a bad idea, a lot of similar challenges in short succession tend to lose interest and popularity fast so you might want to think twice whether you want to post this any time soon. That said, the construction seems simple enough that I'm pretty sure it's been done before. For instance this challenge requires the exact same computation at the core: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57845/8478 (although yours probably allows for other approaches, too).

Answer (score 1):

### *THIS A QUESTION IN PROGRESS*

### ASCII Art converter

see [ASCII Art](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ASCII_art) on Esolangs

Your task is to take input of a brainf*** program and output its equivalent ASCII art program. Your challenge: You may not use the following symbols in your program: `\ / - | _ #` Standard loopholes not allowed...

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins

#### OR

### ACII Art Interpreter

Your task is to create an interpreter for the ASCII art language.
ASCII Art is a variant of brainf*** where characters are instead ASCII art figures 5 lines tall.

`<` looks like

```
 /
/
\
 \
```

`>` looks like

```
\
 \
 /
/
```

`+` looks like

```
  |
  |
-----
  |
  |
```

`-` looks like

```
-----
```

`[` looks like

```
____
|
|
|
|___
```

`]` looks like

```
____
   |
   |
   |
___|
```

`.` looks like

```
##
##
```

`,` looks like

```
##
##
_|
```

Characters that are less than 5 characters tall may be placed anywhere within the top line and bottom line of input.

```
____________________ top line
     \
      \
      /
     /
        <--- gap because this char is only 5 characters tall
_____________________bottom line
```

There may be any amount of white space between characters. Also characters can be "nested" in each other, as long as they do not touch. EG

```
____ |  ##
|    |  ##
|  -----_|
|    |
|___ |
```

is perfectly valid

Your code should not allow improperly formatted ASCII art, and should print to Standard error. For example, the following code should not work

```
\
 \
  |
  |
  |____
```

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Additional tags: [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Comment: What is the winning criterion (is it codegolf, popularty contest, anything else...), and what is the font to use?

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg By font, what do you mean - the ASCII art page on esolangs depicts what each and every symbol should look like

Comment: Nevermind, I haven't seen this part

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thanks for using the sandbox! Unfortunately, this is basically a dupe of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64040/31625) with a [do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/31625) bit tacked on, so I don't think this will be received well. I'm not really sure if there is a way to salvage your intent, here, but I recommend trying something different. Best of luck!

Comment: **1.** If at all possible, posts should be self-contained. The Esolangs page you link to might change or disappear. **2.** You should specify how the commands should be chained (horizontally, vertically or something else), how they should be aligned, and how much whitespace has to separate them. **3.** In my opinion, forbidding those characters doesn't make the challenge more interesting.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Except my challenge is meant to convert only brainf*** code

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't nearly enough to make it not a duplicate, in my opinion. However, Dennis brings up a potentially interesting point, you may be able to salvage this by also requiring that the code be "formatted" a certain way. I also agree with the rest of the advice Dennis gave you, and I think you should address them before deciding on what else to do.

Comment: What if I change it to a ASCII art interpreter

Answer (score 1):

A [meander](http://oeis.org/wiki/Meanders_filling_out_an_n-by-k_grid_%28not_reduced_for_symmetry%29) is a self-avoiding closed curve which intersects a line a number of times.

Your task is, given a self-avoiding walk on a lattice/grid, produce a meander *a la* the following:

**Input**

```
{{{3, 4}}, {1, 2}, {2, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 8}, {8, 12}, {12, 11}, {11, 10}, {10, 9}, {9, 5}, {5, 1}}
```

**Output**

[image]

or similar.

## Test cases:

**Inputs**

```
a={{{3, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 10}, {10, 15}, {15, 14}, {14, 13}, {13, 8}, {8, 7}, {7, 12}, {12, 11}, {11, 6}, {6, 1}}}
b={{{3, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 12}, {12, 18}, {18, 17}, {17, 16}, {16, 10}, {10, 9}, {9, 15}, {15, 14}, {14, 13}, {13, 7}, {7, 1}}
```

**Output**

[image]
[image]

In the above examples, the numbers correspond to a grid, bottom to top, left to right, so `1` is bottom-left, and `18` on a `3*6` grid is top-right. The orientation of your grid doesn't have to follow this order: it can have any desired orientation.

You can assume dimensions of the grid are given at the begining of the input, as per the obove examples.

Feel free to use either pre-existing images - *eg*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

or generate your own. This is Code Golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm still not clear how the points relate the the final image. For the pre-existing images, can we use them at no bytes cost? Is the code for loading them free?

Comment: @xnor I think you are right - it is not clear as it stands - think I will leave it on the back-burner for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

## Pluralize Words [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(DISCLAIMER: In this challenge, several exceptions and rules are not accounted for. Many plurals are based on sound and not spelling, and still others have no set guidelines. Please do not use this as an actual set of rules for making plurals.)

A lot of questions here require using different Algebras. ... Algebra? Algebrae?

OK, that's it. We're going to get to the bottom of this.

Your challenge is to write a program that accepts a word as input and outputs the plural (in standard English rules).

### Rules on making plurals

- Words ending in `s`, `x`, `z`, `ch`, `sh`, `o`, `ex`, or `ix` have `es` added to them. (For example, `box` -> `boxes`)
- Words ending in y preceded by a consonant have the `y` removed and `ies` added to the end. For example, `cherry` -> `cherries`. (Words like `day` with a vowel before the y are treated as normal.)
- Words ending in `f` or `fe` are treated as normal.
- Words ending in `us` have the ending changed to `i`. (For example, `alumnus` -> `alumni`)
- Words ending in `is` have the ending changed to `es`. (For example, `oasis` -> `oases`)
- Words ending in `um` are changed to `a`. (For example, `medium` -> `media`)
- Words ending in `a` are changed to `ae`. (For example, `antenna` -> `antennae`)
- All other words have `s` added to the end.

Several rules have been omitted for simplicity:

- You do not have to account for irregular plurals like `sheep`. If `sheep` was inputted, you would return `sheeps`.
- The `o`/`f`/`fe`/`ex`/`ix` rules have lots of exceptions. `knives`, `matrices`, etc. I can't find any pattern, however, so these are simplified to one rule.
- `chateau` -> `chateaux`, `man` -> `men`, `child` -> `children`, `foot` -> `feet`, and `mouse` -> `mice` have been left out due to ambiguity. You can replace these with `chateaus`, `mans`, `childs`, `foots`, and `mouses`, respectively.
- Words are counted based on spelling, not sound. TimmyD mentioned in the Sandbox:

  > For example, Czech (as in, a person from the Czech Republic) goes to Czechs ("checks") since the ch is pronounced like ck.

  Here you would output `Czeches` (as it is spelled with a `ch`).

### Input

A single word, like `challenge`. The input will only contain letters a-z.

### Output

The pluralized word, based on the rules above, like `challenges`. You may have a trailing newline.

Output may be case-insensitive.

### Test Cases

```
algebra
algebrae

shoe
shoes

fax
faxes

datum
data

bunny
bunnies

qlwlsh
qlwlshes
```

## Meta Questions

UPDATE: I've answered these questions myself. Do you guys think it's ready for posting?

- Is this a duplicate? (No, other similar challenges have different scoring)
- Are there any special cases I left out? (Probably but they'd over-complicate things)
- When researching this I discovered there are a LOT of little rules. I've omitted some here, but is this too complex to be a feasible challenge? (No)

  - In addition, have I left out too many rules? (Adding any more would make it too complex)

Comment: The problem is that English handles its pluralization (and `a`/`an` distinction) based on the vocal pronunciation, and not by the letters themselves. For example, `Czech` (as in, a person from the Czech Republic) goes to `Czechs` ("checks") since the `ch` is pronounced like `ck`. I think the simplifications you have here are OK, so long as you're very explicit that there are a lot of exceptions that aren't accounted for.

Comment: Also, relevant [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/english-pluralization)

Comment: @TimmyD Interesting. I'll double-check the edits I made to make sure those strange cases don't slip through.

Comment: I think the `f` rule could be left in, since it's pretty consistent that `f` and `fe` become `ves`. I can only think of a few exceptions to that rule. A better title might be "Pluralize Words" (since pluralize is actually a word). I think if you just need to follow the rules and not worry about exceptions, it wouldn't be too complex.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/39837/53880) and [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4971/53880). However, I prefer this one to the others since this explicitly states the rules your program should follow.

Comment: @BusinessCat Those are different, scoring is based on the number of wrong words there. Here, this is a code-golf for shortest code that properly prints plurals (with some exceptions.)

Comment: My answer to "*Is this too complex to be a feasible challenge?*" is "Yes". Natural language processing in general (and especially where the language is English) is a better fit for challenges which score by performance against a large suite of manually curated test cases than pure [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 1):

## Find the Watermark

At the moment, I don't have time to outline this properly. The idea is simple: Find the watermark in an image. The implementation, however, is obviously not simple. Since watermarks can have a variety of characteristics, I'd like to admit a variety of answer styles and make it a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). Some ideas for the output format:

- Return coordinates of the (centre|corner(s)?) of the watermark
- Return a line in some form (e.g., endpoints or equation) that runs through the watermark
- Return an image that contains only a mask matching the watermark

Input, obviously, would be an image containing a watermark. Images without watermarks are not valid input; as such, submissions do not need to handle them in any special way.

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Comment: I fear that this is far too vague, and probably too difficult.

Comment: Maybe a [tag:test-battery] tag?

Comment: Yes, seeing the proposed test cases would give a much better idea of whether this is realistic.

Comment: I hereby encourage any member of the community to take over this challenge. I have no experience with graphical I/O, and I don't foresee myself gaining any in the near future. I doubt that I can write a reasonable spec; also, I'm just not that interested in it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

## whispering and SHOUTING

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Typing in all caps on the internet is often called "shouting". For the sake of this challenge, I'll call typing in all-lowercase "whispering".

### The challenge

Write a complete program that can be run in two different ways: whispering and shouting. The "whispering" version of the program must be written in all-lowercase characters, and it should print `whisper` to STDOUT. The "shouting" version of the program will print `SHOUT`. The shouting version must be the *exact same* program as the whispering version, but with all lowercase letters replaced by the uppercase version of the letter. Everything else must be identical.

### Rules

- No standard loopholes
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins!

Comment: Is shortest program in bytes?

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify that

Comment: Though I'm not too sure if I want to keep the restriction of not containing the words because it feels kind of arbitrary and that isn't the point of the challenge

Comment: It *may* be a "Do X without Y" question, which could be bad if not done carefully.

Comment: @ColdGolf The difference between this and a do X without Y is that this challenge focuses on actually doing the X (a non-trivial task) instead of focusing on not using Y. Still, I think I'll get rid of the restriction because a) I'd like to focus more on the X and b) the restriction is trivial to circumvent (simply use concatenation)

Comment: What about characters that don't have a case? Or characters that have more than two cases? Is the program restricted to ASCII?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman characters without a case don't have to change. What character has more than 2 cases? And it's whatever encoding the program uses.

Comment: [Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma) has three total variants. Not restricting this to ASCII makes it seem rather odd. Couldn't a language totally avoid the problem by writing the program in caseless characters and then checking like `A > 65`? Additionally, some characters (i.e. small caps) look like they should have lower case variants, but don't AFAIK. What standard of considering things lower case should we follow? Without restricting or clarifying this, I think this is too unclear.

Answer (score 1):

## Switching lines

Let's say you have a string of text:

```
Hello, World! Today is a
most glorious day. In fact,
it's another day. Woohoo!
```

This string has three lines. We can call them lines 1, 2, and 3. (Or, if you prefer zero-indexing, lines 0, 1, and 2. I'll be using one-indexing to describe this challenge.)

Let's also say we have a mapping of line numbers to line numbers, such as `1 => 2, 3 => 1, 2 => 3`. We will interpret this mapping as a method of "switching" lines with each other; the first rule switches line 1 with line 2, then line 3 with line 1, then line 2 with line 3. This would make the string look like, with intermediate steps:

```
Rule: (initial)
1. Hello, World! Today is a
2. most glorious day. In fact,
3. it's another day. Woohoo!

Rule: 1 => 2
2. most glorious day. In fact,
1. Hello, World! Today is a
3. it's another day. Woohoo!

Rule: 3 => 1
2. most glorious day. In fact,
3. it's another day. Woohoo!
1. Hello, World! Today is a

Rule: 2 => 3
3. it's another day. Woohoo!
2. most glorious day. In fact,
1. Hello, World! Today is a
```

Notice how the rule describes lines to be switched, not merely lines in that index. So each line has a permanent, associated line number.

Any rule such as `1 => 1` is effectively a no-operation.

**Objective** Given a list of numbers in any convenient format (e.g. an array of pairs of integers, a list like `A B\nC D`, a list of numbers, etc.) and a non-empty string of text, perform the action described above.

---

### Meta

is it a good idea to do line identity instead of line locations?

Comment: So the requirements are 1) number the lines; 2) apply the permutation which results from composing a series of simple swap permutations, each of which must be interpreted in the light of the previous ones? The lines really seem to be superfluous: the core of the question is the permutations, surely?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I suppose that's true. It would certainly simplify the questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Tweetable Video

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [printable-ascii](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printable-ascii) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

This challenge is inspired by the [Encode Images into Tweets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11141/encode-images-into-tweets-extreme-image-compression-edition) challenge, extending the idea to now attempt to compress video into a series of "tweet" sized messages where the number of tweets == number frames of the video.

The competition is to compress 450 frames of video into 450 (or less) tweets of 140 charactes ( 114.97 bytes per tweet, total max 51737 bytes).

Original frames as [Video](https://youtu.be/w7GuHLsBUM0), as [PNG images](https://github.com/klana001/TweetVideo/blob/gh-pages/out1.7z) [**Sandbox note:** Higher quality version will be uploaded soon]

Reference solution frames as [Video](https://youtu.be/sZXzuWKzDPA) [**Sandbox note:** Reference solution will be expanded once challenge changes stabilized]

#### Rules:

These rules are the based from rules in [Encode Images into Tweets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11141/encode-images-into-tweets-extreme-image-compression-edition) modified to accommodate multiple frames that will yield the resultant video.

1. You must write a program that will communicate via std in/out based on the communication protocol defined below, ultimately producing a series of tweets that will, when fed back to your program, produce image frames of the video.
2. The text created for each 'Tweet' by the program must be at most 140 characters long and must only contain characters whose code points are in the range of 32-126, inclusive.
3. The source video will be 450 frames of [Big Buck Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Buck_Bunny). Frames can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/klana001/TweetVideo/blob/gh-pages/out1.7z)
4. Frames will be width 320 pixels and height 240 pixels @ 24 bit RGB, each channel having 8 bit precision.
5. Your program should be able to compress other video sources at same resolution.
6. Your program can use external libraries and files, but cannot require an internet connection or a connection to other computers.
7. The decoding process cannot access or contain the original images in any way. (Clarification use of corpus images is allowed as long as these images do not contain direct or manipulated original image frames)
8. Use of video codecs or existing libraries that perform video compression are not allowed. This is to encourage experimentation and originality rather than simply calling libraries. Note that use of static image compressors/ libraries are allowed.
9. [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

#### Communication Protocol

1. All communication is via std in/out.
2. The controller program will launch your program with no command line arguments.
3. The controller will either initiate a one of the following sequences commanding to your program and expecting results.

Note the sequences are described below in the following format:

```
<Comms direction from controller perspective>, <seq number>: <Transmitted Data> - <Information>
```

For Encoding of the frames:

```
Output, 1: ENCODE\n - Indicating that the controller will be sending frames for your program to compress.
Output, 2: <number of frames>\n - String indicating number of frames. i.e. 450
Output, 3: <number of bytes for image data>\n - String indicating number of bytes of the current image data. e.g. 32145
Output, 4: <image data> - sequence of bytes of length defined in output line 3. The is the image data. The image data is a 24 bit image in PNG format
Repeat from output seq number 3 for the number of frames in output seq number 2.
Input, 1: <Tweet>\n - encoded image data. upto 140 characters, whose code points are in the range of 32-126, inclusive. A zero sized tweet will indicate end of all tweets.
Repeat from input line 1 for 1 to up to the number of frames in output seq number 2. Note a zero sized tweet will indicate end of all tweets.
Output, 5: END\n - Indicating that all processing has finished and your program should quit gracefully.
```

For Decoding of the frames:

```
Output, 1: DECODE\n - Indicating that the controller will be sending tweets for your program to decompress.
Output, 2: <number of tweets>\n - String indicating number of tweets. i.e. 450
Output, 3: <Tweet>\n - encoded image data. upto 140 characters, whose code points are in the range of 32-126
Input, 1: <number image frames decoded>\n - String indicating number of image frames that have been decoded as a result of the provided tweet. If 0 then no images have been decoded for this tweet.
Input, 2: <number of bytes for image data>\n - String indicating number of bytes of the current image data. e.g. 32145.
Input, 3: <image data> - sequence of bytes of length defined in input line 2. The is the image data. The image data is a 24 bit image in PNG format. 
Repeat from input seq number 2 for the number of frames in input seq number 1.
Repeat from output seq number 3 for the number of tweets in output seq number 2.
Output, 4: END\n - Indicating that all processing has finished and your program should quit gracefully.
```

4. Your program will be restart between the encoding and decoding phases.

#### Scoring

As an attempt to model the human visual system in a simplistic manner, JPEG quality levels are used as an analogue. Each frame will be compressed to a JPEG using quality levels 0.01 to 1.0 in 0.01 increments. The PSNR of these JPEG compressed versions are calculated and added into a data structure. Additionally, each frame will be resized by half and the JPEG encoding and PSNR calculations performed and added to the data structure. The resizing and calculating will repeat until a single pixel is left.

The result of which will be a scoring continuum of visual 'quality' from low (single color frame) to High (near-identical to original).

Thus, scoring will be objective by means of the following formula:

```
JPEG_QUALITY_LEVEL_PSNR = a pre-computed data multi dimensional structure consisting of the
                          PSNR for incremental JPEG quality levels for each image frame of
                          the video. The entries into this structure for each frame is such
                          that higher indecies are deemed to be of more similar to the
                          original.

Score = SUM of (index of closest matching entry in JPEG_QUALITY_LEVEL_PSNR for given
                original frame and given PSNR of decoded frame)
```

#### Controller

[**Sandbox note:** Controller is to be created]

#### Refrence Solution

[**Sandbox note:** Reference is to be created once question stabilizes]

### Sandbox Questions

Ok, so this is my first question ever posed to codegolf and I am very keen to get feedback on how to better present the challenge.

Some areas where I would like specific feed back is the objective scoring mechanism... i purposely avoided direct PSNR as the score as it is very limited for scoring video quality, being biased toward blurry images, however other algorithms are too complex or not defined. So as a compromise I am using JPEG compression as an analogue for the Human Visual System. Effectively matching a given solutions output frame to original frame PSNR to a JPEG compressed, at a given quality level) version's PSNR and using that match's index in sorted JPEG quality order as input for the score.

Is the protocol clear enough? if not what would be a better way to present it?

Comment: "*I introduced it so that solutions that take all the frames then perform processing over all the frames would be at a clear advantage over those solutions than work over a much shorter frame period.*" I'm not seeing it. If I process all of the frames then the first frame will probably use a lot of tweets and the subsequent ones fewer, so I'll be penalised for the first frame.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Indeed, that is the point i am ?trying? to make, In the fantasy world where video by tweets is a feature desired by users, having to wait until all the tweets are received before playing the video would be very annoying. So this part of the scoring is to give those solutions that return frames quicker in response to provided tweet(s) an advantage. I am thinking that it may be not that "interesting" or "fun" to have this modifier. I think i shall remove it unless some people think it has some worth.

Comment: The point *I* was trying to make is that the feature of the scoring system seems to me to penalise the approach which you say it's trying to promote.

Comment: oh i apologize, i think i misunderstood. Yes, in the example you have given it will penalize that solution, however it would be less penalized than a solution that waited for all tweets, but more penalized than a solution that immediately gives an image frame after each tweet. i.e. the fantasy user would have to wait longer than if the solution produced images after each tweet. Hmm, given the confusion i will remove the modifer as it will be difficult to tune the "negative" effect as to not completely favour immediate frames vs better quality frames.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## Interpret MSF-!

*[Beca](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79350/interpret-dogo?s=1|1.7329)[use](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck?s=2|1.5538) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37014/interpret-pronounced-slashes?s=3|1.2941)[re](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/interpret-a-circuit-diagram?s=4|1.2193) [are](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71004/interpret-the-pig-series?s=5|1.2193)[n't](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93599/interpret-repetition?s=6|1.2020) [eno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/interpret-whatfuck?s=7|1.1700)[ugh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84914/interpret-kipple?s=8|1.1096) ["Int](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65584/interpret-stackymath?s=9|1.0980)[er](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/interpret-fish?s=10|1.0980)[pret](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/634/interpret-befunge-93?s=11|0.9804) [X"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/interpret-your-lang-but-not-yourself?s=12|0.9550) [chal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69505/interpret-functional-basic?s=13|0.9221)[len](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/585/self-interpreting-interpreter?s=16|0.6537)[ges.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48649/interpreting-fish-no-not-that-fish?s=17|0.5082)*

MiniStringFuck (or MSF-) is a brainfuck derivate made by @ErikTheGolfer, with two commands, operating on one cell:

<kbd>Instruction</kbd><kbd>Action</kbd>                                                                               
<kbd>+</kbd>               <kbd>Increment the memory cell. If it reaches 256, wrap to 0.</kbd>
<kbd>.</kbd>                <kbd>Output the character in the cell.</kbd>

or a bad-looking table:

```
Instruction, Action
+, Increment the memory cell. If it reaches 256, wrap to 0.
., Output the character in the cell.
```

---

### Task

Your task is to, given a string of MSF- code, containing only printable ASCII characters, output what it would print.

The string may have other characters than `+` and `.`. Treat them as NOPs

### Example

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.                    Set cell to 48 (0) and output
                                                 +.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.  Keep adding and outputting until 57 (9)
```

### Test Cases

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+. -> !"#
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+. -> 0123456789
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+. -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ -> (no output)
```

Comment: Will the input string ever contain other characters? If so, should they be treated as NOP/comments?

Comment: @Geobits Yes and yes.

Comment: This is basically "Parse unary numbers", and as such I think it's a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76756/194

Answer (score 1):

### Leaderboard golf: [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111735/leaderboard-golf)

Answer (score 1):

## Interleave your code with the input

Given an input string, interleave this string with the source code of your solution.

For example, if your code is `abcd` and the input is `1234`, then your program must output `1a2b3c4d`.

If your code is shorter than the input, then it must loop back to the beginning of your code. For example, if your code is `abcd` and the input is `123456`, then your program must output `1a2b3c4d5a6b`.

If your code is longer than the input, then only part of your code will be interleaved with the input. For example, if your code is `abcd` and the input is `12`, then your program must output `1a2b`.

#### Inputs and outputs

- The input string will only contain characters which are valid string characters in your language.
- The input may be taken through `STDIN`, as a function argument, or anything similar.
- The output may be printed to `STDOUT`, returned from a function, or anything similar.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm not even sure that this is possible.

Comment: Why would it not be possible? The only potential problem I see is being closed as a dupe for being a straightforward generalised quine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't understand how being a "straightforward generalised quine" makes it a dupe (of what?). I don't see how this is more straightforward than say [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89400/input-%e2%88%a9-source-code) nor do I think it is a dupe simply because source code is involved.

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/194

Answer (score 1):

### Priority to the right

Your task is to regulate traffic on a crossroads. There are 4 roads coming from north, east, south and west.

The input is a string representing the upcoming traffic on each road. 
For example, `NNNWS` indicates there is a total of 5 cars: three at the north, one at the west and one at the south. The order has no importance here, `NNNWS` is equivalent to `WNNSN`.

You must output the order in which the cars should go, using the priority to the right rule: cars coming from the south must let cars coming from east go first, east gives way to north, north gives way to west and west gives way to south.

For example, with the input `NNNWS`, the south car should go first, then the west car, then the 3 north cars. The output should then be `SWNNN`.

There are some indecidable cases, for example `NS` or `NNWSE` : you should then output the string `stuck`.

**Test cases**

```
N => N
NW => WN
NWS => SWN
SNW => SWN
SSSSS => SSSSS
ENNNNES => NNNNEES
NS => stuck
NNWSE => stuck
```

Answer (score 1):

### golf.ko - Kernel module golf

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A Linux-specific challenge.

Implement a Linux kernel module which `printk`s `Hello world` upon loading, in some compiled language.

---

Source file, linker scripts and command lines, Makefile content (if any) are all counted towards the byte score.

You may expect kernel version to be 4.1 or 4.4.

The kernel is assumed to be running. It's built, not cleaned source code is assumed to reside in `/usr/src/linux`. In addition you may expect the system to be Debian and to have working [DKMS](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelDKMS).

Comment: Maybe can be a [catalog](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10129/7773).

Comment: What does it mean for a kernel module to "*print*"?

Comment: Issue behaviour similar to `printk` kernel API function in C. Output message to logs, to console, to `/proc/kmsg`. Shall definition what exactly is a `printk` be included? Obviously user is expected to call the function inside kernel, not re-implement `printk`.

Comment: I see: "*printks*" just *looks like* a typo, it isn't *really* one. That could be clearer if you wrote "*`printk`s*", and clearer still if you link to a man page or other documentation. But if you're requiring use of that library, you can pretty much rule out answers in languages other than C and maybe Rust (since what other languages will have bindings for it?), and I wouldn't be surprised if there's nothing interesting left to golf and you just get one answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Maybe just exclude `printk` requirement and require just some code derived from posted source code to be executed? Or just the endless loop (it should be doable in almost any language, is API-agnostic and is observable)?

Answer (score 1):

## Random Quine

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) (something related to languages?)

You are to write **N** programs in **N** langauges (at least 2) that satify the following properties:

1. For each program **P**, the program **P** must produce an output **O** that is equal to a random program **Q** that you wrote, including **P**.
2. No two programs **P** and **Q** may be equal.

Let's say you have two programs, `ABCD` in language Bar and `1234` in language Baz. Then, `ABCD` must produce each of `ABCD` and `1234` with nonzero (but not necessarily equal) probability. Similarly, `1234` must output `ABCD` or `1234` with nonzero chance. Note that the chances do not have to be same for each program.

Comment: Higher **N** being winning doesn't seem to be viable on it's own as I think this could be done essentially forever. Will it be something like total length of all **P**s divided by **N**?

Comment: 1. On clarity: it's not clear what the requirements are for which programs each **P** must produce with non-zero probability. All of them? At least two different ones? ("At least one" would satisfy the stated properties, but not the explanation in the example).  2. On boringness: the programs can just be identical apart from an integer or string literal which they ignore when executing and replace at random when outputting. So a [generalised quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/194) of half of the [tag:random] challenges would meet spec.

Answer (score 1):

---

## Introduction

The challenge is to determine if two complex lines intersect.

## Challenge

Given two lines made up of multiple straight line segments determine if the lines cross at any point.

Input can be in the format of you choice that takes a series of [x,y] coordinates.  All coordinates will be integers (positive or negative)

Output will be truthy if the lines cross and falsey if they don't cross.

There will be no coincidental points and no segment of one line will terminate at a point touching the other line (there will be a clean cross of line segments if the case is truthy).

This is code golf so shortest answer wins

## Example Input and Output

For the examples formats are given as

> Line 1: [[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]...,[Xn,Yn]] Line 2: [[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]...,[Xn,Yn]]

Examples

> Line 1: [[0,0],[1,1]] Line 2: [[0,1],[1,0]] = TRUE
>
> Line 1: [[2,2],[1,0],[0,2]] Line 2: [[0,1],[1,1]] = TRUE
>
> Line 1: [[1,3],[2,9],[3,6],[4,7],[5,4],[6,1]]  Line 2: [[2,6],[3,5],[5,2]] = FALSE
>
> Line 1: [[0,6],[3,8],[5,5],[8,5]]  Line 2: [[0,4],[3,7],[5,4],[7,6]] = TRUE
>
> Line 1: [[2,2],[3,2]] Line 2: [[1,1],[10,4]] = FALSE

[image]

Please let me know your thoughts, first puzzle.

Comment: What about the case where one of the line segments "touches" another.  That is: one of the end points of a line is on the other line.  Would that be considered "crossing" or not?

Comment: @DarthRubik tried to clarify, don't need to handle that case.

Comment: All of the test cases have `x` increasing strictly monotonically. Is this guaranteed, or could line segments be vertical or even loop back? If you don't guarantee that input will avoid those situations, please add test cases to cover them.

Answer (score 1):

## Raytracing/Raycasting

Here is a 256*256 heightmap. Your challenge is to render it, in minecraft-style blocks, using some form of raytracing.

[image]

#### Fundamental Definitions And Clarifications

These are all straightforward and fairly obvious but I'm being explicit so that what follows is (ideally) unambiguous.

- Let each pixel represent `1x1` metre, for ease of thought.
- This image is a top-down view. The bottom-left pixel of the image in screen space is at `[0,0,0]` in world space. The bottom-right pixel of the image in screen space is at `[255,0,0]` *(i.e. the next full tile to the right would be anchored at `[256,0,0]`)*. The Z-axis increases away from us in world space so the top-left pixel is at `[0,0,255]` and the top-right-pixel is at `[255,0,255]`.
- As you are looking down to the floor at the moment, you have positive height and the vector from your eye to the image points in the direction of `[0,-1,0]`, so the camera which corresponds to the above image has a world-space coordinate of something like `[128,300,128]`.
- It shouldn't really matter, but let's take the red channel as holding the height. A red channel value of `foo` puts that pixel at `y=foo`. The tallest possible pixel would have world coordinate `[x,255,z]` with `0<=x,z<256`.

#### Aesthetic Definitions

- Each pixel effectively represents a tower some number of 1x1x1 solid cubes. The edges of these blocks should be rendered sharply at 90-degree angles. If you were to convert this scene to triangles, each normal would be along one of the major axes. You can think of blocks having end-caps on their top (which is the floor, to us), and walls are extruded between neighbouring blocks as required. **There are no holes in the rendered surface**. You can assume all renderings will be from above (extra implied geometry below the floor doesn't matter).
- As well as the heightmap, the world contains **one camera** and **one light** source. The light casts hard shadows, so every rendered pixel will require two ray casts. Light falloff is inverse-square. You may optionally gamma-correct the result.
- Pixels on a surface which receive no light should be black. Pixels of rays which do not hit any surface should be magenta: `rgb=(255,0,255)`.

#### Input Parameters

- The camera is defined by position `P=[px,py,pz]`, a `T=[tx,ty,tz]` target point, and a field of view `FOV`. It renders `WIDTH x HEIGHT` images such that the target point appears in the centre.
- The camera is orientated such that it yaws, then pitches, but does not roll.
- The light is at position `L=[lx,ly,lz]` and casts light uniformly in all directions.
- You solution must be posted with reference image rendered with `P=[80,256,0]`, `T=[128,50,200]`, `L=[256,300,128]`, `WIDTH=400`, `HEIGHT=300` and `FOV=45 degrees`.
- (As reference images emerge I might tweak these parameters.)

#### Free Parameters

- The light can be any colour and brightness you like but the colour and brightness must be inputs to the program.
- Likewise, the colour/material of the surface may be anything you like (except magenta, which is for revealing holes) but these colour/material parameters must be an adjustable input to the program.
- Use any lighting/shader model you like.
- Use fog or other effects if you like. Different submissions are likely to vary considerably in size, so there's room to play a bit.

#### Criteria

- You must post code which can be run as-is, with the specified reference parameters and all your free parameters included.
- You can take the heightmap image as hardcoded in a representation of your choice and this does *not* count towards your golf score. You must post the code which converts an image to your preferred format. This script should either run using common Linux command-line tools, or over an online service. This script should *not* assume that heightmaps are square.
- The output of raw pixel data can be in any format you like (e.g. `[[r,g,b],...]` BUT you must provide a second script, not counted towards your golf score, which turns your program's raw output into some standard image format such as PNG. This script should either run using common Linux command-line tools, or over an online service.
- You must post the final image produced by this method, as well as the code which produces the output which produces the image.

In a nutshell, the above specifies that your output is reproducible, with different parameters and heightmap images as desired.

**The winner** will be chosen a few weeks from now, as the shortest code which conforms to the above aesthetic specifications (e.g. shadows, no holes, etc) and which gives end-to-end reproducible results.

Comment: Maybe include a sample output?

Comment: My own attempt at this is part of a larger, more complex project, it'll be a while :-) In the meantime I was curious if others would find a simplified version of the problem a bit more fun.

Comment: Must run, so will expand on this later, if not within 48 hours then ping me. There are some subtleties with respect to offsets (are blocks centred?) The stuff about fog etc is wasted space, because in [tag:code-golf] no-one will spend bytes on it, so remove it to KISS. I strongly advise before posting to get a test output which two independent programs agree on.

Comment: 1. The subtlety I promised to expand on: does "*The bottom-left pixel of the image in screen space is at [0,0,0] in world space*" mean that the pixel corresponds to the voxel whose coordinates range from `(0,0,0)` to `(1,1,1)` or the voxel whose coordinates range from `(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)` to `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`? 2. Also, what does "*The camera is orientated such that it yaws, then pitches, but does not roll*" mean? Perhaps it could be better expressed by giving the initial up, forward, right vectors and then saying around which axes it rotates.

Answer (score 1):

## First 100 prime numbers in Wentelx87 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

> Wentel consists of, at the basic level, a memory pointer and an instruction pointer. Instructions are stored loaded into memory. The execution pointer moves to the right after executing the instruction at that memory pointer.
>
> The program is loaded into rightmost slot of memory. For example, if your program is `0010 0000 0101 0100`, 
>   then the virtual machine will look like this when started:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0101 0100 (memory)
                                                            ^                   (execution pointer)
^                                                                               (memory pointer)
```

### (from [README](https://github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87/blob/master/README.md))

---

Wentel documentation examples, thorough and clear explanation [here](https://github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87).

Wentel is language that is very hard to program in. Unlike brain**k, functions and GOTOs can be implemented. It emulates real machine code/assembly much better than brainf**k.

Wentel is a simple language.

1. instructions are held in the rightmost cells, one cell = one instruction
2. execution pointer starts out on first instruction
3. execution pointer moves right
4. **the same cells that hold memory hold instructions.**
5. these are the opcodes:

**`0000`** - no-op

**`0001`** - if the current address's value is equal to the value stored by the adress defined by the next word, move the execution pointer to the address pointed to the next word after the word after the current address.

**`0010`** - move memory pointer to address specified by next word.

**`0011`** - deposit the current address of the execution pointer into the current memory address

**`0100`** - increment current memory address

**`0101`** - decrement current memory address

**`0110`** - move memory pointer left

**`0111`** - move memory pointer right

6. and here are the specialized opcodes for output.

**`1000`** - output `0`

**`1001`** - output `1`

---

That was a boiling down of Wentel. Please read the [full docs](https://github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87/blob/master/README.md). Now for the actual challenge. Output the first 100 prime numbers, separated by spaces, in Wentel.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bits wins.

Comment: If you want to encourage an answer to an existing question in a new language, the way to do it is with a bounty on the existing question. If you're worried about losing your rep because no answers will be posted, see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5243/194

Answer (score 1):

A simple but fun code golf challenge!

Given positive integer `n`

create a 2 dimensional matrix where each location is filled with it's xy index (starting from the top left).

For example:

Your grid should look like:
input: 2

```
00 10
01 11
```

input: 3

```
00 10 20
01 11 21
02 12 22
```

Once the grid is created, randomly `fill` each index. This can be with an 'x' or any other way to denote a spot has been `filled`

A complete simulation looks like:

input: 3

```
x x x
x x x
x x x

O O O
O O O
O O O
```

You can use whatever character you want to fill in each location.

**Extra points if you use a GUI and use black squares to fill it in**

You should only `fill` a spot in once so the number of times you fill should be n^2. (So no randomly filling spots until they are all filled you have to check!)

You can refresh the grid however you want. i.e print the grid, make a new line, print again... You can use a timer. However you want to do it to illustrate each step. You only need to refresh when you are `filling` not when you are populating the grid.

An example simulation looks like this:

input: 2

```
00 10
01 11
```

randomed `01`

```
00 10
XX 11
```

randomed `11`

```
00 10
XX XX
```

randomed `11`
re-roll
randomed `01`
re-roll
randomed `00`

```
XX 10
XX XX
```

randomed `10`

```
XX XX
XX XX
```

Complete

Do not display your randomed numbers, the output should tell me which were randomed.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

## Just like magic

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

---

Nowadays, the word "abracadabra" is used mostly in connection with magic tricks. The original purpose of the word had more to do with superstition, and some doctors used it to make lethal diseases go away by writing it in a triangle<sup>1</sup>, like so:

```
A B R A C A D A B R A
 A B R A C A D A B R
  A B R A C A D A B
   A B R A C A D A
    A B R A C A D
     A B R A C A
      A B R A C
       A B R A
        A B R
         A B
          A
```

Your task is to write a program or function that outputs/returns the exact text shown above in as few bytes as possible. The output may contain trailing spaces on each line and/or trailing newlines. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes wins**.

<sup>1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra</sup>

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is it too simple?
- Is it a duplicate?
- Any better name ideas?

Comment: "It's magic, you know! Never believe it's not so!"

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Haha :) though I'm not sure how many people would get the reference. I had to google the lyrics, but the song sounds very familiar. I wonder where I've heard it before...

Comment: Well, it's the same formatting than [Number Triangles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94526/number-triangles), but the task is clearly different. I suppose you could also call it "A Kind of Magic", although the Queen/Highlander reference might be a bit far-fetched.

Comment: The closest I can think of as a dupe is http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65300/8478, but it seems likely that it's shorter to generate each line from the previous instead of generating a string of all prefixes first and the laying it out in a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

### Ungolf batch

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73230/56341) question wants you to golf batch programms. In Batch you can use

```
set x=averylongbatchcommand
%x% arg1
```

which expands to

```
set x=averylongbatchcommand
averylongbatchcommand arg1
```

Your task is it to expand these statements.
As you can also use `set`  for arithmetic purposes like this:

```
set x = 0
set /a x= %x%+1
```

you should ignore the statements where the pattern with `set /a` is applied.
There will never be something like

```
set s=SET
%s% s=%s% a
```

where the variable is assigned using itself as command. But you have to handle things like

```
b:
set a =echo
%a% Hello World!
set a=goto
%a% b
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

### Testcases

```
set s=set
%s% e=echo
%e% I will have to use this exact thing very often because
%e% it absolutely wouldn't be shorter if i just left out these set statements
```

Expands to:

```
set s=set
set e=echo
echo I will have to use this exact thing very often because
echo it absolutely wouldn't be shorter if i just left out these set statements
```

---

```
set s=set
%s% i=0
set g=goto
:a
if %i%==15 (
%g% e
)
%s% /a i=%i%+1
%g% a
:e
```

Expands to:

```
set s=set
set i=0
:a
if %i%==15(
set e
)
set /a i=%i%+1
goto a
e:
```

---

```
set s=set
%s% s=%s% a=
```

Mustn't be supported.

Comment: Too bad the question mentioned has no answers...

Comment: I will probably post It tomorrow, if there isn't any critic.

Answer (score 1):

## Convert Birkana to Hexademical

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [hexadecimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexadecimal)

### Introduction

[Birkana](http://yawar.blogspot.ca/2016/10/the-birkana-hexadecimal-number-symbols.html) is a not-very-well-known notation for hexadecimal using
rune-like symbols. The general structure of a Birkana rune is like this:

```
|\     <-- 0x1
|/     <-- 0x2
|\     <-- 0x4
|/     <-- 0x8
```

The slash or backslash is present if its base number (`0x1`, `0x2`, `0x4`,
or `0x8`) is present in the number, or not otherwise. The pipe is always at
the left-hand side.

For example, here's the Birkana rune for `0xD` (= `0x1 + 0x4 + 0x8`):

```
|\
|
|\
|/
```

### Challenge

Given a Birkana rune as input, write a program or function to output the
corresponding hexadecimal digit.

You may choose to output either lowercase (`a-f`) or uppercase (`A-F`) hex
digits, but they cannot be mixed.

You only need to support the 16 hexadecimal digits and their corresponding
Birkana runes.

### Test cases

```
Input
Output

|
|
|
|
0

|\
|
|
|
1

|
|/
|
|
2

|\
|/
|
|
3

|
|
|\
|
4

|\
|
|\
|
5

|
|/
|\
|
6

|\
|/
|\
|
7

|
|
|
|/
8

|\
|
|
|/
9

|
|/
|
|/
A

|\
|/
|
|/
B

|
|
|\
|/
C

|\
|
|\
|/
D

|
|/
|\
|/
E

|\
|/
|\
|/
F
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is this just binary displayed vertically using space/nothing for zero and a slash for a one? I guess the fact that the slashes alternate could just be ignored, treating each position as either empty or full, which would still give the correct output? If so, is it acceptable to output a hex digit for invalid inputs? This is likely to make a difference to the approaches used.

Answer (score 1):

### Find the least squares regression line

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Background

I'm taking AP stats now, so I figured I'd bring the joy to you all here.

The form of an LSRL (least squares regression line) is  `ŷ = a + bx`.

### Input

Your job is to find the least squares regression line for two data sets (lists), `X` and `Y`. `X` and `Y` will be the same size with at least 2 elements. They will contain positive or negative floats. Input can be taken in any reasonable format.

### Output

The values `a` and `b` in the least squares regression line (LSRL) for the data in `X` and `Y`, where `a` is the y-intercept and `b` is the slope of the LSRL. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) page describes a way to calculate this line.

**This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!**

**Also, built-ins are allowed!**

**Examples**

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] [12.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0] -> A: 11.0 B: 1.6
[1.5, 1.5, 51.0, -15.0] [2.0, 1109.0, 0.003, 2.0] -> A: 314.92 B: -3.7609
[1.0, 2.0] [1.0, 2.0] -> A: 0.0 B: 1.0
[-15.0, -13.0, -163.0, -12.25, -14.41, 100000.0, -630.0, -135.0] [-142531.0, -12.0, 153.0, -135.0, 135.0, 16.0, 21.0, 0.0] -> A: -20285.0 B: 0.20121
[3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0] [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0] -> A: -1.0 B: 1.0
```

Comment: 1. Use the full name in the title, because the title will be shown in contexts where the body isn't. 2. What kind of numbers will `X` and `Y` contain? The test cases use signed integers, but can answers assume that all inputs will be integers, or that all inputs will be floating point numbers? 3. In some contexts, a quadratic can validly be described as a least squares regression line. It would be better to move the definition which makes it clear that it's a linear polynomial to the introduction, before the section on input, rather than having it in the section on output.

Comment: 4. There's more than one way to calculate the gradient, and the method described is not the best one. I would suggest removing that section entirely and having a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression in the introduction.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I have edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Every math language has a builtin for this so it's just `solve(x,y)`. Even without the built-in linear solver, this is just the pseudoinverse of (1,x) multiplied with y.

Comment: I disagree with Peter - for the sake of self-containedness, you should include at least one method of computing the LSRL (and keep the link in case people want to see more methods).

Answer (score 1):

## 2D Poor Man's Plotting!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

### Introduction

Surely you've also come across the problem where you have a multi-dimensional function at hand and want to visualize it (it's just such an everyday problem!). So we need a (programmatic) solution to this. A *memorable* solution, thus obviously the shortest solution is best!

### Specification

#### Input

Your (primary) input will be a function that maps two floats onto another float.

Additionally there are six other parameters (floats), which you may take explicitely or hard-code:

- StartingValueX: 0
- StartingValueY: 0
- EndingValueX: 10
- EndingValueY: 10
- StepSizeX: 1
- StepSizeY: 1

You may take these parameters using your preferred method of input, but please document it (especially how the function should be passed).

#### Output

The output is a formatted string or a printed output (whatever pleases you).

#### What to do?

The introduction already hinted it:
Given a function that takes two floats as inputs, iterate it two-dimensionally and print the resulting values. So the top left entry is the result of the evaluation at (StartValueX,StartValueY) and the bottom right entry is the evaluation of (EndValueX,EndValueY) and then you form basically a table from this by incrementing the StartValue by the respective StepSize for each iteration.

**Formatting guidelines:**
Between each line may be one (or more) empty lines (eg end your lines with `\n\n` in C).
There must be at least one white space between every output number.
All numbers with the same x-coordinate *must* be aligned respectively to their start.

#### Potential Corner Cases

You may always assume a certain function prototype is used.
If `EndValue-StartValue` is not an exact multiple of StepSize (which may happen because we're dealing with floats here) then you shall compute for all `StartValue + k * StepSize` smaller than EndValue as well as for EndValue.
You may always assume the computation results (of the function) are actually representable in your language.
You may not assume that the function is a simple mathematical function (e.g. any valid function adhering to the above conditions in your language must work).
Trailing newlines and white spaces are allowed.

#### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

### Test-cases

Default parameters, `f(x,y)=x+y`
Output:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1):

## Directional Brainf*ck Compiler/Interpreter [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Challenge: Write a Brainf*ck compiler with 4 extra commands.

```
L Set the direction to go left
R Set the direction to go right
D Set the direction to go down
U Set the direction to go up
```

The original commands (altered):

```
+ Increment the cell one
- Decrement the cell one
[ Start a loop, if the cell is 0 then go to the next ]
] end a loop if the current cell is 0. Else go back to the last [ read and continue from there (in the direction you were going last time it was read.
. output the byte at the data pointer.
, accept one byte of input, storing its value in the byte at the data pointer.
> point to the cell to the right
< point to the cell to the left
```

### Compiler/Interpreter

In this case the compiler must either convert the code to another language or be an interpreter and run the code.

This is basically a directional version of brainf*ck. Directions should work the same way they do in `><>`.

The pointer should start at the tape's beginning. It must be infinite in the right direction. Left infinite is optional (if you add it -10 to the score). Upon end of code output (in any reasonable form) the current values on all the stacks. If a `]` is hit before a `[` output a warning (with a message of your choosing). If a `,` is met at the end of the code you can do with it as you please. The program will terminate at the end of the file.

Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: So, what does `]` do

Comment: Taken from Wikipedia: if the byte at the data pointer is nonzero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it back to the command after the matching [ command. @feersum

Comment: You don't need to tell me what it does in brainfuck. I'm asking you, what does it do in *this* language you're defining here?

Comment: @feersum Oh okay. If the byte at the data pointer isn't 0 then instead of going to the next command. Go back to the last `[` found. Should I add that to the challenge description?

Comment: That description doesn't accord with the normal interpretation, which goes to a matching bracket, rather than the last one found. And it still doesn't clarify how it will interact with the two-dimensional aspect. In particular, what direction will the instruction pointer travel after jumping to a `[`?

Comment: @feersum it should go in the same direction it was going last time it was parsed I guess. I thought the last `[` parsed would be better since I can't imagine matching brackets in 2D language.

Comment: You need to specify the behavior in the challenge specification. Personally I don't see an issue with jumping back to the command after the last `[` encountered, continuing in the same direction. 1D programs in this extension that didn't use any of `LRDU` would be compatible with regular brainfuck with that behavior (assuming no mismatched braces).

Comment: Also, what does `[` do if the cell is 0....

Comment: @feersum Jump to the next `]` in the current direction, presumably. That needs to be specified too, though.

Comment: @trichoplax Done.

Comment: Since tags can't be added to an answer, you can use `[tag:code-golf]` to show the tags you are going to use, so it won't be necessary in the title.

Comment: If it's going to be a compiler/interpreter, it may attract more competitors if that is included in the title.

Comment: Is this ready to post?

Comment: It's missing a lot of info. (1) The position and direction of instrucitons pointer at the beginning. (2) What happens upon reaching an edge of teh code. (3) What happens if `]` is hit before any `[`. (4) The usual BF-specific stuff: (a) behavior of `,` on EOF (b) Integer range of cells (c) whether tape should be infinite in one direction, both, or something else. (5) How does the program terminate, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

## Resolve paths [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Convert a path to an absolute path. The path may be:

- relative
- absolute
- contain `~`

If the path doesn't exist, exit with code 1. An invalid path leads to undefined behavior. i.e. *do whatever you want, I don't care*

Test cases, assuming `/foo/bar` is the current working directory, and the username is `~/admin`:

```
<empty string> -> /foo/bar
. -> /foo/bar
.. -> /foo
... -> / # and so on until `...`
~/ -> ~/admin
~/golf -> ~/admin/golf
/bin -> /bin
foobar -> /foo/bar/foobar
.htaccess -> /foo/bar/.htaccess
./buildscript -> /foo/bar/buildscript
doesnotexist -> <exit with error code 1>
```

Don't use an external command or builtin that solves or almost completely solves this challenge.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32568/42963)

Comment: This is very confusing... why does `~/golf` go to `~/admin/golf`? That's not an absolute path is it? Shouldn't `~/golf` go to `/home/admin/golf`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Lang1] vs [Lang2] ... vs [LangN]: Battle of the golfers!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [teamwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) and other tags for the challenge questions, which may be a lot.

> Note: I haven't figured out all the kinks out yet, all I have is a general idea that, with your help, can be put properly into an awesome challenge (I hope). The parts where my ideas are not solid yet have Notes attached to them that must be read.

## Team

In the midst of the nation of SE, there lies a golf field for the community of golfers. These golfers play day and night using specialised clubs (languages) to complete difficult and challenging holes (challenges). Now it is time to see the best of these golf clubs in the game!

> Note 1: First of all, this challenge is going to be language-specific. I haven't decided the languages yet, but right now I'm thinking around the lines of Java, C, C++, C# since these languages are very well known, unlike the other esoteric languages.

You, the golfer, are to choose one golf club out from these [Lang1], [Lang2], ...,  [LangN]. You will team up with other players using the same golf club as you.

> Note 2: Now there is supposed to be a table where the players can edit into this challenge (once I post it) to join a team. After ~1 week from the beginning of the sign-up, people will start competing in the challenge.

This will be a sort of golf relay, where every player must only complete 1 hole, no more, no less. But of course, each player may help teammates to complete the holes using the minimum number of shots (bytes) as possible. All golfers, of every team, will be playing using the same playing field, in this case `UTF-8`.

## The Challenge

There will be a list of challenges [see Note 3] to be completed by the team. Each team member must complete 1 challenge only. After a fixed amount of time (see Note 3), all team members must have complete their assigned challenges (see Note 4). I will sum of all the bytes used by each team to figure out the winning team (see Note 5)!

> Note 3: Either I will provide all the challenges, or each team member may give 1 challenge to the challenge pool. Challenges can range from anything like quines and "Hello, World" challenges, to more complicated ones, like solving advanced mathematical (pardon me) mumbo jumbo and outputting complex sequences. Every team completes all of these challenges (see Note 4). 
>  The time that I have decided, so far, is to give the entire team 3 weeks (subject to change) to complete their challenges.
>
> Note 4: Each team member complete 1 challenge. However, if the team sizes are different, the team with the greatest number of members will have to complete *all* of the challenges. The other teams only have to complete as many challenges as members, so that there will be one for every member.
>
> Note 5: The scoring will be the number of bytes used by each team, summed up, and then divided by the number of challenges completed.

### Answering

Here is the format to each answer:

```
#Language, challenge-number, byte-count in UTF-8
```

for example:

```
#Java, #34, <s>463</s> <s>444</s>  <s>442</s> bytes
```

### Summary

To sum it up, here is the process that this challenge goes through:

1. People who want to play must choose one team to be on, if they want to play.
2. After registration is over, the games begin: each player is to choose *only* one challenge and give a golfed answer. (Other players of the same team are allowed to help teammates)
3. After some time, when all the challenges are attempted (one for every person, if people haven't answered in this time, they won't be counted towards the challenge), I will calculate the score of each team (using the total bytes used).
4. Leaderboard is announced and the winning team walks away with all the glory!

> Comment any ways this challenge can be improved. My general idea is to implement a *team* game, instead of the standard free-for-all.

Comment: Have a look at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/42963 for some inspiration on what worked and didn't work when a similar team-based thing was attempted.

Answer (score 1):

## King of the Hill: Moon Rockets

This is a challenge where you code bots to compete in an arena. In this case, you code a rocket flying over the Moon. Your goal is to shoot down enemy rockets, while not running out of fuel and crashing into the Moon.

#### Environment

Unlike many KOTH challenges the playing field is continuous, rather than discrete. You are provided with variables for your position, velocity, and the direction you are facing. Each turn, you are given a list of all the rockets you can "see" (all rockets less than 10 units away). You return a turning speed, thrust and whether you want to fire missiles.

#### Arena

The arena wraps left-right. There is a floor; if you crash into it going faster than 4 m/s, you will explode. There is no ceiling, but you do have a limit of 10 fuel units. This can be refueled by landing on the floor going less than 4 m/s.

#### Missiles

Every turn, you have the option to fire missiles. Missiles go in the direction you are pointing, at a constant velocity 5 m/s faster than you were when you fired. If they come within a 1m radius of another rocket, they explode and destroy it.

#### Gravity

Gravity is a constant force of 1 downward. With a max thrust of 2, you can accelerate at an equal rate in the opposite direction.

Pastebin for current controller code: http://pastebin.com/FNyjrJfr
No tournament code is in place yet.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Spacewar KotH](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/king-of-the-hill-spacewar)

Comment: The controller seems to set the step size at 0.5s. Does that give enough time to take evasive action at all, given the missile speed and sight range? (Even discounting step size, with max thrust of 2, it seems like it's going to be hard to outmaneuver something going possibly several times faster)

Comment: Additionally related to step size, how are collisions handled? If I'm a meter away from you and fire a missile that goes 7m/s, can it miss by overshooting in that half second?

Comment: Can spaceships collide with each other, or only the surface?

Comment: 1. Continuous presumably means floats, which means possible disagreements over the results (because e.g. Java doesn't strictly apply the IEEE-754 spec unless you tell it to). 2. The spec should say at the very least what information is available to the bots. Does the "*list of all the rockets you can "see"*" include velocity, angular velocity, etc. or just position?

Comment: I assume one win condition is "last rocket flying", but what about stalemates? Is there a "last turn", since it seems like a couple pacifists could land/refuel forever?

Comment: @Geobits - the collisions are handled point-by-point, so yes, you could miss someone right in front of you if you have a high closing speed. I think evasion is possible as long as you have at least 1 step of warning.

Comment: @Geobits Spaceships can't collide in the current code. If they could, what should define a "collision"? Currently they are modeled as point objects.

Comment: @PeterTaylor they can access velocity etc. as well as position. I think this might be required as if a rocket is moving fast you need to lead it with the missile.

Comment: @Geobits I could add a condition that limits the total turns. Does 50 turns seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

## C Compiler

Implement a basic C Compiler.

You do not need to implement the libraries. Compiler would output an object file containing a function, that would be linked with some libraries using GNU binutils `ld` and run.

No function calls, unions, structs, casts will be used in the test cases.

Test case:

```
int test(int i, int j) {
  int x[10][20];
  int s = i + j;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    while (j < 20)
    {
      j += 1;
      x[i][j] = i * j;
    }
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    while (j < 20) {
      s += x[i][j];
    }
  return s;
}
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: What *does* need to be implemented? A question should ideally be self-contained, but if there's too much information to fit in the post then it should contain links to the relevant specifications.

Answer (score 1):

## HamSort a list of strings

Given a list of strings, sort them in a manner such that the Hamming distance between each is minimal.

The Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number of positions where the corresponding characters do not match. For example, the Hamming distance between `apple` and `ample` is 1 since only the second characters of each do not match.

```
apple
ample
 *
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- Each string in the input list will have the same length and will consist of only the letters in the English alphabet. You may assume all to be either uppercase or lowercase.
- If there are multiple possible solutions, you may output any number of them.

### Test Cases

```
<to be created>
```

Comment: The Hamming between consecutive pairs? If so, what is to be minimized? The sum of the Hamming distances? Their maximum?

Comment: What is (for this challenge) the hamming distance of strings without equal length? Or will the list contain only strings of the same length?

Comment: @xnor It's still a work-in-progress. I'd like to have the problem be minimizing the Hamming distance between the consecutive pairs, but that problem might be hard enough that the only golfy solution would be generating all permutations and testing each pair. Then a length `n` input would have a length `n-1` Hamming distance array where each value is minimal. If you have better ideas that could still capture the spirit of this, feel free to suggest them.

Comment: @Laikoni Yes, Hamming distance is only defined between strings with equal length and one of the rules was that the input array would only contain strings with equal length.

Comment: I think it's NP hard to find the path that minimizes total Hamming distance by reduction to Ham-Path. So, I wouldn't expect anything better than brute force there.

Answer (score 1):

**How fast (slow) is your language?**

This is a question both to test your coding skills but also to speed benchmark your favorite language.  The code snippet will make a table of the fastest code per language. It is related to previous [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [challenge][1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97060/calculate-the-permanent-as-quickly-as-possible) so you may find some of the code there a useful starting point.

The challenge is to write the fastest code possible for computing the [permanent of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) whose entries are floating point in the range -1 to 1.

The permanent of an `n`-by-`n` matrix `A` = (`a`<sub>`i,j`</sub>) is defined as

[image]

Here `S_n` represents the set of all permutations of `[1, n]`.

As an example (from the wiki):

[image]

In this question matrices are all square and will only have the floating point values in the range `-1` to `1` (excluding both ends).   I will construct all tests in such a way that the permanent is also in the range `-1` to `1`.

**Examples**

Input:

```
[[-0.34389946 -0.811193  ]
 [ 0.62778788 -0.09918764]]
```

Permanent:

```
-0.47514655471
```

Input:

```
[[-0.34389946 -0.811193  ]
[ 0.4783581  -0.56636227]]
```

Permanent:

```
-0.19326906099
```

**The task**

You should write code that, given an `n` by `n` matrix, outputs its permanent.

As the output will never be bigger than 1 in absolute value you do not have to worry about overflow. However you do have to worry about numerical accuracy. All answers should be correct up to 8 decimal places.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any available language and libraries you like but no pre-existing function to compute the permanent.

**More to be added..Work in progress**

Comment: "*All answers should be correct up to 8 decimal places.*" Are you sure this is possible? I suspect that finding the permanent has similar problems of ill-conditioning to finding the determinant.

Comment: So this is your posted permanent challenge but with floats? I don't see what that's so different as to warrant another challenge.

Comment: @xnor The only differences are a) it avoids all the big int stuff that turned out to be crucial in the last challenge and b) it will have a code snippet and will be designed to encourage answers in lots of languages. Not just fast ones.  The idea is to show how slow (fast) your language is and it can serve as a fun sort of language competition/benchmark.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's a very interesting point. I am not sure of the answer but I was going to choose random orthogonal matrices (I need to change and add examples) so maybe ill-conditioning will be very rare?

Answer (score 1):

## Modular Reverse Recursion Sequence

Given any number `n > 0`, let `r` represent the reverse of the number `n`. Iterate until the final result is zero, passing the result of each iteration back into the function using recursion or a methodology of your choice by performing the below operation:

- If `r > n` for that iteration the result is `r % n`.
- If `n > r` for that iteration the result is `n % r`.
- If `n % r = 0` or `r % n = 0`, you terminate iteration.

Take the intermediate result of each execution and store them in an array for the final answer.

Lets walk through an example where `n=32452345`.

```
54325423 % 32452345 = 21873078 # r > n, uses r % n
87037812 % 21873078 = 21418578 # r > n, uses r % n
87581412 % 21418578 = 1907100  # r > n, uses r % n
1907100 % 17091 = 9999         # n > r, uses n % r
9999 % 9999 = 0                # r % n = n % r = 0, terminated

Result: [21873078, 21418578, 1907100, 9999]
```

Another example `n=12345678`:

```
87654321 % 12345678 = 1234575 # r > n, uses r % n
5754321 % 1234575 = 816021    # r > n, uses r % n
816021 % 120618 = 92313       # n > r, uses n % r
92313 % 31329 = 29655         # n > r, uses n % r
55692 % 29655 = 26037         # r > n, uses r % n
73062 % 26037 = 20988         # r > n, uses r % n
88902 % 20988 = 4950          # r > n, uses r % n
4950 % 594 = 198              # n > r, uses n % r
891 % 198 = 99                # r > n, uses r % n
99 % 99 = 0                   # r % n = n % r = 0, terminated

Result: [1234575, 816021, 92313, 29655, 26037, 20988, 4950, 198, 99]
```

A final example `n=11000`:

```
11000 % 11 = 0 # n % r = 0, terminated

Result: []
```

Comment: If you have to include `0` as the final element, it might be better to say "if n = 0, terminate", since terminating when `n=r` doesn't really include `0`, because the final modulus (e.g. `9999%9999`) was never done.

Comment: @Geobits Edited to remove 0 from the list of final results, nice catch. That was the only part I did manually.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplified maze-solver

A spin-off from this question [Textual maze solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/textual-maze-solver)

Write a program, that will take an bunch of 0's and 1's as it's input (see below), and a half-solved maze as it's output. The program should take 1's as walls and 0's as corridors. The output should should show `99`'s as walls and a number as the distance from the start of the maze. The maze should have no real entrance/exit; instead, the entrance is the square in the 2nd column of the 2nd row.

Examples (allowed cases):

```
Input               Output

1 1 1 1 1 1         99 99 99 99 99 99
1 0 0 1 0 1         99 00 01 99 05 99
1 1 0 0 0 1   -->   99 99 02 03 04 99
1 0 1 1 0 1         99 10 99 99 05 99
1 0 0 0 0 1         99 09 08 07 06 99
1 1 1 1 1 1         99 99 99 99 99 99 

{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},         99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},         99 0  1  2  99 16 17 18 99
 {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},         99 99 99 3  99 15 99 19 99
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},   -->   99 6  5  4  99 14 99 20 99
 {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},         99 7  99 99 99 13 99 21 99
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},         99 8  9  10 11 12 99 22 99
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}         99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
```

Examples (not allowed outputs and inputs):

```
11111 10101 10101 10001 11111  --> 9999999999 9900990699 9901990599 9902030499 9999999999
```

Notes:

- as seen above, the input and output must be bunch of numbers separated by whitespaces, commas, full stops, newlines, parenthesis (and so on), and mustn't be in a single row
- you can output `01` instead of `1`
- cases where the distance is over 99 don't need to be covered
- the program doesn't need to solve the maze, just to find the distance from the start
- two fields connected diagonally aren't next to each other
- it's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)

Comment: it makes more sense to show walls as `##` or `||` etc, instead of an integer

Comment: The restrictions on the format on the output and inputs don't add anything to the challenge (imo) : the interesting part is solving the maze.

Comment: @Dada They allow the program to be shorter, at least in most languages I know.

Comment: @Flp.Tkc See the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Defs need to fix up layout

[Very much a WIP]

## Maze battle

In this challenge, bots will team up, navigate around a maze and try to destroy the enemy team's artifact, and protect their own.

A maze might look like this. Note that the bots will receive numbers rather than ascii art, which represent their vision, and the objects they see.

```
+---------+-+---+-------+++-+-+---+-+-------+-+-----+
|         | |   |    #  | | | |   | |       | |     |
+-+ +-+-+ + + + +-+-+ +-+ + + + + + + + +-+-+ +-+ + |
|   |         |         |     | |   | | |   |     | |
| +-+-+ + +-+ +-+ + + +-+ + +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+ +-+ + |
|       | |   |   | |     | |   |         | |   |   |
| +-+-+-+ +-+-+-+ + + + + +-+ +-+-+ +-+ + + + +-+ + |
|   |     |       |   | |   |   |     | | |       | |
| + + +-+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+ + + + + + +-+ + + |
| |       |                 | |   | | |     |   | | |
| + + + +-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+ + + +-+ +-+ + +-+-+-+ +-+-+
| | | |     |   | | |     |     |   | | |           |
| +-+ +-+ + +-+ +-+ +-+-+ +-+ + + + + + +-+-+ +-+ + |
|   | |   | |           | |   | | | |   | | |     | |
| +-+ + +-+ +-+ + + + +-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+ + + + +-+ + |
|     | |       | | |   | | | | | |         |   | | |
| + + +-+ + + + + +-+ +-+ + +-+ + +-+ +-+-+ +-+ +-+-+
| | |   | | | | |   |   |       | |   | |       |   |
| +-+ + + +-+ +-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+ + + +-+ + +-+-+ +-+ |
|   | |   |         |       |   |       |   |       |
+-+ +-+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+ + + + +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+-+
|   |   |   |   |   | | |     |     |   | |   |     |
| + +-+ +-+ + +-+-+-+ + + + +-+-+-+ +-+ + + +-+ +-+ |
| |       |   |   |     | |         | |   | |       |
| +-+-+ + +-+ +-+ + +-+-+-+ + + + +-+ +-+ +-+-+ +-+ |
| |   | | | |       | |   | | | | |   |     |     | |
+-+-+ + +-+ +-+-+-+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+-+ +-+ +-+ + |
| | | | |   |           |     | |     |       | | | |
| + + +-+-+ + +-+ +-+-+ + +-+-+ +-+ +-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+
|   |     | | |             |   | |   | |     |     |
+-+ +-+-+ + + + +-+ +-+-+-+ +-+ + +-+ + +-+ +-+ +-+-+
|   | |   |   |   | |     | |   |     |   |       | |
| +-+ + +-+-+ + +-+ + + +-+-+ + + + + + +-+-+ + + + |
|       | |           |       |   | | | |     | |   |
| +-+-+ + +-+ + +-+-+ + + +-+ + +-+-+ + +-+ + + +-+ |
|   | |   |         | | | |   |     |   | | | | |   |
+-+ + + + + + + +-+ + +-+-+-+-+ +-+-+ +-+ +-+-+ + +-+
|       |   | | |           |     | | |   | |       |
+-+-+-+ + +-+-+-+-+-+ + +-+-+ +-+ + +-+ + + + +-+ + |
|     |   | |         |     | |     |   |       | | |
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ + +-+ +-+-+ + + +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+-+
|     | | |     |   |         | |           |   |   |
+-+ +-+-+ + +-+-+ +-+-+ +-+-+ +-+ +-+-+-+-+ + +-+ + |
|               | |   |                 |   | |   | |
+-+-+ +-+-+-+ + + + + +-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+ + + +-+ +-+ |
|       |   | | |   |   |           | | | |       | |
| +-+-+ + + +-+ +-+ + + +-+-+ +-+ + + + +-+-+-+-+ + |
| |       | | | |   | |       |   |     |           |
+-+-+ + +-+-+ + + +-+ +-+ +-+-+ + +-+ + + +-+-+ +-+-+
| |   |     |   | | |   |       |     | |     |     |
| + +-+ + + + + + + + + + + + + +-+-+-+ +-+-+ +-+-+ |
|       | | | |    #  |   | | | |       |     |     |
+-------+-+-+-+-------+---+-+-+-+-------+-----+-----+
```

Bots receive information about their current environment. They will receive a 8 lines of numbers, representing their view in each of the directions. vision is blocked by walls, and walls only, so at the end of the line of sight is a wall.

Numbers represent the following things:

- 0 represents a space with nothing in it.
- 1 represents a friendly bot
- 2 represents an enemy bot
- 3 represents your team's artifact
- 4 represents the enemy team's artifact

To destroy the enemy's artifact, you have to shoot it a bunch. heaps. So, you probably want to bring that artifact to your team, or your team's side, so that you can shoot it more.

When you die, you respawn after 5 turns.

At the start of the round, bots spawn into the first third of the maze on their side. when respawning, they also spawn into this area.

Comment: Nice idea! Would be better if it was Java :D

Comment: @KritixiLithos: No

Answer (score 1):

## Format an XML file

Your task is to parse an XML snippet (not necessarily an entire file) and format it. I am explicitly making this simple to encourage extremely golfed code.

The formatter should transform XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <div class="community-option">
        <input id="communitymode" name="communitymode" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="communitymode" title="Marking an answer community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone.">community wiki</label>
        <a href="www.hoehel.be"><i>My inner web developer hates me</i></a>
        <b>BOLD</b>
    </div>
    <iframe/>
</body>
```

into formatted text like this:

```
?xml
body
    div
        input
        label
        a
            i
        b
    iframe
```

### Rules

The main element does not get a indent, every layer deeper does get an extra indent. An indent is either a tab or 4 spaces.

When there are multiple root elements, they simply are added below eachother with no indentation. The `?xml` element is not different from any other element.

The XML will have a space after each element name, so if there is a CDATA element, it will be formatted as `<![CDATA[ (the data)]]>` and will need to be formatted as `![CDATA[` at the correct indentation.

Also, the XML will not include `>` and `<` except for opening and closing elements.

Comment: In XML, a right angle bracket > [is allowed in an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866706/which-characters-are-invalid-unless-encoded-in-an-xml-attribute). So perhaps include that as a test case, or explicitly state that this will not happen. Also, what qualifies as an indent? One space? Four spaces? A tab character `\t`?

Comment: 1. The example is invalid because (a) it doesn't have a single root element; (b) the `input` element isn't closed. 2. This isn't really pretty printing XML. It's pretty printing the *element structure* of XML. 3. There are a whole bunch of important test cases which are missing. CDATA. Namespaces defined at the root element. Namespaces defined on non-root elements. Elements expanded from entities. There are bound to be some others if you look at the spec.

Comment: @sanchises Reworked the question to avoid problems there.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (a) I'll include that it can be a snippet. (b) Didn't notice it, took some HTML from stackoverflow source code, don't blame me :) 2. Renamed to "formatting" the XML 3. Added workaround for the special cases I could find.

Answer (score 1):

## Build a learning 20Q bot

Twenty Questions is a verbal game where an 'asker' asks you a series of yes or no questions about an object that you're thinking of. If the 'asker' gets the object correct  after twenty questions, then the 'asker' wins the game. If the asker does not guess the question right after 20 questions, then the 'thinker' wins.

### Input:

Your program needs to take 4 different inputs, non simultaneously. Those three inputs are:

- A category (valid categories are Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing)
- A yes / no input from the user to answer the questions.
- A question input to 'teach the bot', and an object input to show the bot what was being described.

### Output:

Your program needs to play a game of 20 questions, wherein it follows this structure:

- Ask a category like so: "Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):"
- Ask questions based on the category.
- Make a guess of the object like so: "Is it a "[guess]"?".
- IF the guess was wrong, ask what the object was, and inquire the difference between the guess and the object described.
- your program must stop at 20 questions and make a guess. it doesn't have to be random.
- your program must progressively 'learn' as it is played. It must be able to add new questions and objects to guess.

### Examples:

```
⇨Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):  
⇦Food  
⇨Is it  ?  
⇦No  
⇨What is it?  
⇦Marmite  
⇨What is the difference between  and Marmite?   
⇦It has a saying 'You either love it or hate it'  
⇨  
⇨Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):  
⇦Food  
⇨Does It has a saying 'You either love it or hate it'?   
⇦No  
⇨Is it Marmite?  
⇦No  
⇨What is it?  
⇦A Carrot  
⇨What is the difference between Marmite and A Carrot?  
⇦It has lots of vitamin C   
⇨  
⇨Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):  
⇦Food  
⇨Does It has a saying 'You either love it or hate it'?   
⇦No  
⇨Does it It has lots of vitamin C?  
⇦Yes  
⇨Is it a Carrot?  
⇦No  
⇨What is it?  
⇦A Yam  
⇨ What's the difference between a Carrot and A Yam?  
⇦It grows underground.  
⇨  
⇨Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):  
⇦Food  
⇨Does It has a saying 'You either love it or hate it'?   
Yes  
⇨Is it Marmite?  
Yes  
⇨Yay, I Win!  
⇨  
⇨Select a category (Animal, Food, Action, Person/Character, Thing):
```

Etc.

Comment: Pass2: How Can I improve this? I would like some critiques before I post.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57171/32686

Answer (score 1):

## Lasers & Mirrors

ah lasers. they're a modern marvel. From the most common colors of blue, red, and purple to the more exotic cyan, green, and Occasional yellow. One of the most fascinating properties of lasers is their tendency to travel in a straight line, and bounce off mirrors. What fun! Let's simulate that.

consider a square grid of arbitrary size. This grid has four elements, **Mirrors**, walls, spaces, and a single *goal*

### **Mirrors**:

Mirrors comprise only 2 characters: **/ and \**. each of them represents a mirror which is reflective on BOTH sides, and is angled at 45 degrees and -45 degrees respectively. If a laser fits a mirror, it will change direction by 90 degrees, as it would in real life. the direction that the laser goes is dependent of the angle of incidence.

### **Walls**:

Walls also comprise of 2 characters: **| and _**. A wall is simple in that it stops a laser, and ends the beam. The Direction of the wall is irrelevant. | and _ are functionally the same!  If a laser hits a wall before the goal, then the solution is faulty.

### **Goals**:

There is one goal per puzzle input to the program. The goal is represented by a ***** somewhere on the grid. The objective is to get the laser to pass through the goal from any cardinal direction.

### **Spaces**:

Spaces are the easiest to recognize, as they're any character that's not already mentioned. for the purpose of the puzzle, you can assume that all spaces are **.** (dots).

## Input:

Your input will be a square grid with grid elements and one goal. The grid will always be square, and will always have a goal. grid elements will be entered in a list that is either 1 row tall (eg: the 3x3 example puzzle would be `[".","_",".","|","*","|",".",".","."]`) or in a square set of arrays (eg: the 3x3 puzzle would be [`".","_","."],["|","*","|"],[".",".","."]`).

## Output:

Your output will be a number which represents where the laser should be shot from in order to get to the goal. You can see how outputs are numbered below. If there is more than one solution, you may either output any or all solutions.

## Examples:

```
 ..9
0._.8
1|*|7
2...6
 345

Output:4
```

This example shows how a grid will be numbered. it is numbered counter-clockwise  starting in the top left at 0 such as there are 2 numbers for each row and column.The laser is placed at the position of the number and shot in at a multiple of 90 degrees.

The correct answer is 4 because the goal is enclosed by walls except where the 4 is located, which the laser gets shot in (in this case up). In the picture below, you see the same puzzle, but numbered correctly, along with another test case.

[image][image]

<sub>the directions on each example show the direction of travel for the laser for each number</sub>

This is a code golf, so the shortest code will win! good luck!

Comment: What if there's more than one possible solution?

Comment: @Gareth thank you. I added to the post: "If there is more than one solution, you may either output any or all solutions."

Comment: Any other feedback?

Comment: `If a laser hits a wall parallel to the direction that it's going, the laser will still stop.` I'm not sure if this is meant to say perpendicular or parallel. Also, whichever type of wall stops a given direction of laser, what does the other type of wall do? Can a laser pass straight through in that case? Or is the direction of the wall a red herring? Do all walls behave the same regardless of direction?

Comment: `the compass directions on each example show the direction of travel for the laser for each number` Usually "compass directions" would be used for North, East, South, and West. If you want to you up, right, down, and left, it's probably clearer to just leave out the word "compass" and just say "the directions".

Comment: `you can assume that all spaces are . (dots)` so I don't understand the `X`s in the last example.

Answer (score 1):

## Produce a quine of length *n*

Write a program that, given a number *n*, produces a quine in your language of length *n*. If your language cannot have a quine of that length, it does not need to be generated.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/12537) are forbidden.

The quines that are generated must be [proper quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/12537).

Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Comment: Is there a minimum/maximum n? Plenty of languages don't have a 1 or 2 length quine, for example.

Comment: @Geobits How botu now?

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'm not sure how to prove it for some languages, but I'll leave that to answerers :)

Comment: The `!` in the title made me think that the quine had to have length `n` factorial, whereas the text says `n`. You should remove the `!` in the title.

Comment: @Fatalize Okay. Done.

Comment: Regarding what @Geobits said, with the current wording I'm definitely worried since answerers would need to prove that they've got the minimum length quine covered.

Comment: Sp3000's concern is definitely valid. It would mean that you can only answer in languages where the shortest known quine has been proven to be optimal. Also, I'm not sure it's terribly interesting in most languages, because you can usually just insert spaces or no-ops into one or two places and the code remains a quine.

Answer (score 1):

## Find the Mersenne Twister seed [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Given a sequence of **N** 32-bit unsigned integers, find a 32-bit seed for the [Mersenne Twister PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Algorithmic_detail) (specifically, MT19337) such that the first **N** 32-bit unsigned integers produced are the input sequence.

### Rules

- Solutions will be tested and timed on a free [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) workspace (512 MB RAM, 1 8-core CPU). Full CPU specifications can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Mego/aa84d3706bf7414f2aa6409512076417).
- There will be 50 sequences used to time solutions, each containing at least 20 and at most 50 integers. All sequences will be generated using CPython 3.4's MT19337 implementation (the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Modules/_randommodule.c)).
- Brute force (by way of iterating through all possible seeds) is not allowed, as it would take an obscene amount of time to run all 50 timing cases with such a solution.
- Hard-coding seeds is not allowed, as it undermines the point of this challenge.
- I reserve the right to change the timing sequences to different sequences of similar complexity if needed, such as in the event that two seeds are found for the same sequence.
- Please include instructions on how to run your solution, including installation instructions for any software that is not included with a standard Ubuntu installation.

### Test Cases

Note that the seeds given may not be the only seeds which produce the given sequence (if other seeds are found, please let me know). These smaller test cases are provided for verification purposes only, and will not be used for scoring.

```
[859552199, 418371998] -> 765976290
[3575669016, 3345750943, 1425199743, 3641622143, 468413882, 1201820413, 440223465, 4032367274, 1303769163] -> 3089232394
[3301913871, 2465802243, 3612732284, 2327984155, 3125193467, 1186355054, 3586515345, 1676699096] -> 3317482306
[1187719129, 4252341260, 3652285377, 2546267472, 259146681, 3132024105] -> 618872552
[567043356, 3386297553, 3291980436] -> 2064328469
[2371812852] -> 3402334589
[2169144927, 1612138200, 2367065602, 3106703576, 3360699020, 2044583150] -> 1508970517
[4264152408, 93510901, 2140553491, 2298459244, 3988997159] -> 3805008435
[815695699, 3390998580, 1837233431, 35472600] -> 1298560578
[2785297506, 692193253, 1505379580, 2810620241, 2299478120, 233996693] -> 1856467397
```

### Timing Cases

These are the 50 sequences, along with the respective seeds that produced them, that will be used for scoring solutions. Once again, if any other seeds are found that produce the given sequence, please let me know.

```
[3626764237, 1654615998, 3255389356, 3823568514, 1806341205, 173879092, 1112038970, 4146640122, 2195908194, 2087043557, 1739178872, 3943786419, 3366389305, 3564191072, 1302718217, 4156669319, 2046968324, 1537810351, 2505606783, 3829653368, 3900315155, 938204377, 2167613558, 598176026, 1210484339, 600203567, 3246154361, 407295012, 2655874620, 3433407905, 1075916535, 4240245955, 3907330410, 2287343378, 4221031477, 3028691745, 3479856542, 2585149702, 3874773259, 631194409, 1332073689, 424185324, 3134603515, 316721330] -> 0
[3393124633, 2450474977, 1966463085, 3673681320, 1729202683, 1167867720, 325264180, 3917283871, 100160351, 791524511, 2930202830, 3113143968, 1502082504, 1809749915, 418618347, 1516663034, 578608165, 3127414055, 3472262548, 308161377, 135281507, 4131277967, 3953099834, 1042116387, 1985078128, 1789355090, 2975834429, 2756451880, 1853842973] -> 80552670
[3501423986, 1904817736, 3722254077, 4209805889, 624241735, 3072497443, 3348948634, 948724253, 2775088165, 653145320, 699931897, 2271688288, 965327734, 3611254581, 4021716510, 3489649715, 590896686, 2492882151, 2449284001, 1709766651, 2373030892, 1906330141, 3281376004, 542155191, 654946082, 3866707349, 675539429, 3153689518, 2192976919, 2369760520, 1789539597] -> 123863960
[161627675, 758641073, 3882484966, 1142624247, 4128058828, 2063104815, 1532506610, 4133456839, 2543581728, 18178196, 2276191025, 6278001, 3128406689, 2146406812, 39141315, 1050571803, 2511216100, 2411368419, 3269811767, 815334548, 3812711899] -> 178693462
[1006603821, 2040840228, 2217261808, 3301867033, 3944952417, 1692780898, 40334807, 2573488161, 1195239502, 1063781197, 758636410, 1944506134, 1022411961, 3709537934, 175021745, 3183030828, 1196557078, 11946672, 1551403327, 4143434962, 3283348277, 1825370082, 2293735756, 429108850, 745523037] -> 227497455
[2252079699, 1086590868, 525211993, 209343944, 1861419840, 2057307759, 2083384643, 2590024292, 4135416707, 3508386594, 1358765199, 3089076939, 3719484781, 516962076, 4107295833, 723033883, 1857756581, 434940583, 919038598, 2441529245, 1687894943, 13982251, 1940221612, 220848786, 1518435648] -> 260282679
[1821793358, 3054510267, 1906284293, 3380915352, 2593544407, 3915598365, 216223976, 4179796969, 2252681786, 35956624, 2373486206, 877849443, 3555235079, 3667331109, 2387597923, 2892840935, 1697182374, 4016309999, 3498537950, 2841634562, 3522184350, 1705717875, 4162597164, 2056807023, 2211204973, 3267303967, 3919558114] -> 325889376
[1201670212, 746140380, 1320204973, 751872422, 3310421711, 1963946901, 625374447, 2435010607, 3055683554, 3426449636, 4008426547, 337682689, 4056318014, 2315028303, 3896431367, 3153777187, 595649858, 3945299365, 113301178, 437820390, 2219035549, 284287245, 3156511236, 3954981533, 599197497, 3946167954, 3728124202, 733618224, 2033404503, 2973733622, 2705618778, 3966553008, 4036118888] -> 389267947
[1910148876, 4015517082, 1214608849, 988091919, 2525094197, 81939600, 3978887728, 2847303411, 66064807, 3605598571, 819502713, 233898591, 1970756897, 2621444751, 213250142, 3439913424, 1332746382, 4063692407, 869169264, 660008864, 2526902458, 3155477426, 1686496804, 3877857092, 4248058769, 2220603751, 465407251, 3418337662, 362811108] -> 424148743
[2663034465, 347641133, 1266329350, 494434286, 24416336, 1697535896, 233051569, 1134030615, 821790629, 1645020605, 2310228737, 63596966, 3832219398, 465243130, 4070794284, 1062758865, 2070536142, 2272514237, 440192702, 3490367376, 3000125608, 1175130963, 339129292, 1200804986, 3560746354, 1043913893, 489469329, 3588157041, 415367051, 1506938118, 519839008, 3921307375, 1017013313] -> 481818733
[2125426152, 580419999, 1942656966, 733532664, 1002041383, 4276401064, 3164003602, 1600445806, 87486541, 585241213, 1822489492, 3670405099, 2371866217, 293071217, 1698095716, 2860716495, 4096732631, 860271933, 1698519068, 1453446230, 2296564613, 1034887983, 3124580892, 3613882243, 3142206150, 1201496338, 262241539, 2658580629, 75299337, 1543495990, 1079614000, 1988996951, 1393947112, 3686457188] -> 503218192
[849928291, 3109119200, 641398141, 953565598, 1651963094, 2973763708, 2409024299, 2638872282, 3438675501, 2024561790, 2574711112, 2224233243, 2145875524, 2483785498, 832036542, 2756591965, 804169437, 1610259885, 1727659540, 3804671151, 2651460465, 3679117113, 3392652401, 4291100134, 3315401681, 4150630548, 3255282492, 1793428708, 4213220288, 1275054855, 3395683809, 126422719, 747072718] -> 529806420
[3795382423, 2318193600, 2941259533, 1429473204, 3841712189, 908410440, 2163447895, 2266401416, 1962272288, 2172290597, 903602965, 2493475709, 1557270830, 1269693466, 1882416966, 1675172531, 2727910931, 67882201, 982110502, 922191612, 1147478737, 1527639226, 1162436584, 3427111171, 1012039523, 775426178, 2235111095, 838473449, 3547292154, 2331447259, 2482093779, 3522096001, 978885775, 911597256, 4199754157, 884328339, 3958245046, 3701693539, 2205845644, 737996384] -> 594670421
[2281257517, 3184614238, 760843542, 2349085191, 3946149756, 3843515781, 357391440, 280771960, 1523563345, 1988608601, 3428233753, 100999796, 1858706576, 3053822297, 2013347998, 2869736987, 3049191880, 2683304507, 2165662057, 1644801829, 3174344328, 516799881, 2817748912, 680940874, 60488796, 440310808, 4238771580, 3333869324, 3437732706, 2291819087, 2904810286, 643100619, 2444662123, 2814934785, 3198564042, 3050641347, 2644737611, 1044358220, 2729428974, 2696207835, 1949284287, 2602160488, 4077269219, 843097934] -> 608761482
[2459044101, 3628291690, 21901316, 1607776779, 574126446, 2632595613, 1898457307, 1993218217, 2268071755, 2262630078, 1334308000, 2756814507, 1322265974, 493521136, 3513003023, 1998755513, 501729387, 461623974, 2703701229, 3074392802, 2895338933, 1257991758, 1147599903, 2188879650, 2802233695, 1049885503, 67969151, 3855902849, 1481701505, 2592817148, 3215907335, 3924969407, 91996333, 857125517, 3408363147, 4006870634, 998389513, 1316925910, 1621658875, 2583060764, 3809067813, 4122609293, 3970592027, 529557207, 1717219729, 2504378950, 418151974, 1944676036, 4136632810, 2747386509] -> 672575322
[58833619, 2580439730, 3693390914, 2286941505, 2380251005, 860188183, 1775128121, 1286129564, 1885665593, 2208299577, 4157266729, 3426550994, 3918528183, 4277973044, 3399609402, 1027156209, 2127983039, 4014806283, 1680366681, 2338809246, 2450101289, 2369487851, 2470761981, 4146252501] -> 758102662
[1228778451, 3161629785, 956090791, 2661866534, 3797423759, 387813121, 686718911, 1671912681, 3122216050, 3708361254, 2450007821, 562470295, 2371567740, 594715145, 1539207036, 1044745741, 3799733486, 3957279143, 3072889407, 43156136, 564713293, 3478075046, 3706967146, 3687044887, 992776898, 3807405066] -> 829276193
[4181681092, 472808862, 2820379353, 1971138909, 957029949, 383690688, 1619203644, 40060279, 799380031, 2522476881, 3052161194, 1101783645, 550394884, 1003243703, 1139176364, 637909704, 1746995412, 3569010375, 2962331845, 1221693446, 1622613434, 2503259347, 1956882342, 3173044265, 1239439145, 842693462, 2538205226, 2451274505, 4212820092, 3591867315, 1233020299, 978021001, 3148810648, 1811827712, 2638973530, 815364991, 1169900461, 1109925685, 856009157, 3254416301, 2037813477, 3945026418, 1535198958, 4259784019, 573350683, 1682977388, 1817703645, 2576589136] -> 898248134
[3182465441, 38281954, 424174823, 2654611156, 2877159272, 723093605, 1443837986, 3392781854, 2463922103, 4286449851, 538962217, 2130457280, 2178815165, 3486677232, 4058242555, 491907811, 162839736, 1759357975, 870141283, 1495756753, 1216746993, 1937724479, 1514235325, 4184006461, 3436845854, 2401877503, 610797147] -> 913459250
[1149034119, 2642531102, 1662163608, 3290983280, 819699523, 515983953, 2696922239, 2166479741, 1179733281, 2022256392, 1626594590, 543353369, 3692263091, 2392093428, 4014491227, 1041518429, 1713650051, 3538550903, 3376348599, 4277108217, 2867735513, 82177527, 10764183, 2126826329, 1028783725, 2271873691, 213268477, 2609718986, 3495904404, 913207638, 1265558725, 2980124058, 303469040, 253105205, 495410356] -> 931867201
[1077541173, 465200833, 3196368211, 1288748206, 2815478016, 1065298665, 2884065004, 392702413, 3587996620, 2894220485, 3226548573, 145951050, 956741233, 2456765795, 3978933657, 1007424556, 2169150234, 3651822773, 1565891297, 510586439, 2219790712, 422126653, 1640535295, 2992880885, 3691821384, 1555208492, 2642710071, 2625348100, 578265950, 592730275, 2092195932, 2504727970, 2149376041, 3179917702, 141987426, 2680075044, 656985656, 2153196909, 4149347932, 2216899428, 2639954700, 3190665042, 2786390314, 2974431514, 1505784370, 3602363995, 1699665616, 327189341, 335160466] -> 945442081
[1284631810, 3717268552, 2270237312, 1334241593, 1477854231, 3138477902, 3837857694, 3586498067, 1959233909, 3891506078, 2756512687, 2553842301, 964459746, 1395510385, 1185295577, 3096625618, 3145085801, 2953203657, 412902939, 3850708910, 2893328412, 2046860068, 86811187, 1188173782, 1294786028, 3044338056, 1040690464, 2128428491, 2571424043, 467837042, 3752155615, 4020048256, 3119445970, 2240289832, 1491368301, 3651270856, 2456196179, 378459336, 188104463, 777143930, 1824526143, 4060407078, 3866701738] -> 1005490735
[329511653, 2198540059, 2154958918, 378488687, 1460553211, 2529097663, 2295211009, 68583162, 1430570391, 1601101442, 1075009348, 2795773614, 833830658, 903181786, 633114581, 3292534356, 3245176784, 2582500259, 3943169203, 1130082435, 3079387854, 3150805871, 1721482617, 2291158702, 3225790458, 1468813727, 862011357, 4268175908, 3661137987, 464141661, 3956758980, 353701536, 1341361227, 809582799, 3968372465, 4111098095, 2898048807, 1509470117, 3255194829, 1330296075, 3520527115, 3736908846, 168999059] -> 1056211089
[1981947965, 3374825360, 3953254353, 1846368367, 1512467473, 3858309918, 4274851313, 787575622, 1876080592, 73919936, 3951066372, 730226758, 3289279637, 768907525, 1773361296, 821210337, 823248190, 869737395, 1360958003, 37854528, 426098214, 2732039516, 64754302, 3276807872, 3816769165, 991587659, 2262236344, 2500333010, 544193426, 1576372318, 2228843007, 2361635236, 2149913894, 3651360213, 2399010654, 4269441712, 1500948518, 3962883634, 1885037482, 2608182179, 3516218188, 513897987, 4242749462, 3892663321, 3922003874, 2123606394, 1383207752, 2867973529, 3840556114, 2969243741] -> 1071722183
[2514263486, 742731713, 3234620175, 3101660088, 2571087369, 3985627296, 3534135449, 2957356517, 2720311929, 2985074784, 2621199558, 3407431088, 2711831197, 1247421057, 3794320157, 1180925811, 1569942151, 2629267152, 173488457, 1406704148, 3969219352, 291552269, 1333806964, 2203738485, 1554560925, 496218017, 1379546509, 2539796280, 4118468566, 2328295795, 884528669, 123600717, 1597383076] -> 1093875318
[1521547521, 982639096, 3108583938, 3860926389, 1477036165, 2087376039, 953332718, 1432039007, 836148138, 3081500185, 396473811, 1621365414, 3796659618, 3939606659, 4248871833, 2917576264, 2729341943, 2981171481, 2311970081, 150264587, 2215220955, 995666639, 452785817, 758560294, 2134005122, 39617150, 1283053470, 4198921194, 2492185018, 595457083, 1042642207, 545670342, 4068770955, 749869737, 984770127, 663196981, 1849907933, 1443537561, 3860175505, 1016163998, 3260982442, 3769639327, 2728953690, 1556597597, 1877966580] -> 1155984918
[1198705327, 1935517658, 503589232, 1577874702, 627636752, 3338218922, 1157893341, 3491377096, 158028724, 2472091015, 1488124620, 2401465711, 3064309912, 1501000204, 3549612642, 2584717560, 1744885213, 4114571438, 1885581118, 2912594621, 3206412254, 4218195409, 2855464167, 2517461088, 685010709, 2000660923, 3562767265, 1193468772, 1470300123, 819551295, 2007863203, 980161306, 717575858, 2022655390, 1011703442, 1190149434, 182438707, 4158211886, 2175561856, 3060913999, 1239412823, 2397907962, 3942897187, 2435381198, 4007365042, 1591831562, 1664232451] -> 1198085477
[3487615865, 4016084043, 1447817513, 2774535999, 1987172957, 3906060658, 3082008686, 88752056, 1947416015, 3376238098, 3503927625, 342228658, 2709452172, 1070052314, 3791872618, 1290870698, 587900606, 1133043554, 671196454, 3876594873, 526665632, 165876551, 3122917378, 4053700531, 1298948490, 1351144611, 563691115, 322287271, 2461185743, 3663527460, 4222266716, 3553092834, 4168116886, 1291668088, 2033147092, 17653398, 3675413239, 2758765766, 2242336270, 734645239] -> 1234710497
[4199109099, 1728109096, 1057011054, 312030739, 490158329, 2571270959, 1337574406, 3037342898, 2943362559, 468588625, 1215641907, 891368463, 3446982561, 146537280, 1406572684, 1996341215, 1239450385, 3239123491, 2654855274, 584040319, 664433665, 3282777560, 3498456462, 398718226, 3318895203, 4109932784, 435092929, 3761442422] -> 1281039914
[330441100, 3682376585, 1548511518, 1012361554, 1641750013, 1347050521, 2746331107, 363031882, 3664742187, 263887825, 3045968855, 4047861721, 4201376344, 2013802400, 43925321, 2057073856, 974221675, 1240944962, 3823005386, 3154676709, 1649841356, 3211264096, 355417272, 2640980835, 2706339938, 987877841, 110633642, 4200784138, 3756125284, 471091914, 3370617977] -> 1307906352
[3242988428, 4255969082, 867271806, 415292052, 3609803438, 416630352, 3232953772, 4269951801, 350204559, 4181264343, 2332795572, 2668659134, 2628956236, 3596517643, 2454368561, 1369266677, 3672701863, 388613580, 1479812495, 2141142524, 2486572053, 2320908196, 393062185, 1938229604, 231136143, 1626064567, 1493467817, 1983339349, 894785483, 44315897, 1514887732, 1864793575, 3953707615, 3492718672, 3522516821, 289358385, 2227856486, 256540739, 4213343606, 200728817, 3396994332, 3845507785, 220892851] -> 1358830177
[3696325595, 95369954, 135918350, 487636311, 825705453, 3049392697, 841126004, 1979734631, 507462131, 1964376824, 3031319264, 3487421046, 2192402845, 3792297163, 3808487536, 1516405605, 664293073, 613658148, 4063050354, 1921745034, 2258497732, 3473698642, 3256102715, 1916456581, 1185919167, 3315712023, 2955859300, 1784025278, 2641317925] -> 1394873382
[2775177776, 3943074566, 1008831348, 423577731, 2936039382, 3419907541, 3346657170, 1767888023, 2549910502, 1510292917, 609091982, 3619041655, 1071140841, 4210891014, 4197129534, 4002247218, 1785145415, 773140313, 850187206, 3695148850, 1699963321, 2029501148, 2273345989, 2045294772, 2490424114, 3670522622, 1903814852, 2845243988, 547217989, 814736327, 1178316093, 3421797242, 583834194, 560861293, 1728122240, 1143281622] -> 1418337751
[3909221229, 1543378013, 3578599386, 1821301593, 382025872, 3090149061, 2799832135, 2969167740, 3214053618, 2459088339, 61851869, 2988154510, 3405155263, 1143312722, 3055626916, 1306722473, 2424970867, 3838250998, 2541260784, 3634562987, 91009990, 228167376, 144739158, 69758376, 1416179539, 175832649, 1058618668, 3141319060, 2603813691, 3448922532, 3563483339, 2187253777, 3939459963, 729053170, 348198400, 2818894106, 4163690148, 4269596985, 1550179869, 2888474224, 977138852, 2267335031, 1039633247, 331897176, 3493431132] -> 1440945260
[548460784, 2008846553, 4095226690, 2537987040, 1412322911, 295388541, 388770296, 2073124976, 4254588769, 2032785043, 3714052855, 653890260, 3378524009, 4169809326, 1850329785, 2009334592, 2701527530, 260935905, 1081271463, 3349408130, 187425716, 588199859, 1037983019, 3586620795, 4254384458, 3345512384, 1424865889, 1577623131, 3897199153, 2727265103, 3204931862, 4089210973, 1909632078, 3588030047, 1946727191, 502364265, 2290334448, 2873594561, 1542446006, 3459132329, 4292608386, 3741690622, 165647068, 1253913368, 1993997790, 2812680991, 2352267270] -> 1500826128
[888893887, 2614777345, 2033163377, 4036989271, 3569896418, 1268962278, 1146226964, 107044610, 2147272927, 3436615686, 1202308143, 1325516848, 2994121867, 973196789, 3793281340, 3099942299, 2472036270, 1798140896, 2858254867, 2204354371, 3472459738, 826142039, 4066377434, 2519409484, 1777413266, 3493671143, 551412865, 886786197, 3882384707, 1172607108, 636563066, 190968362, 3994307050, 3757375918, 2755608252] -> 1566530912
[2820693508, 1716694240, 2268887698, 1296436510, 2916995305, 3041798596, 3096982293, 177546898, 3065170162, 933607211, 102294817, 1801218436, 102569645, 2901869379, 2714886480, 119387632, 656198271, 1388322584, 2775933520, 255861774, 653410879, 121504271, 3607745288, 2230556561, 2594802791, 1189055855, 1111240008, 2530579856, 936965766, 3263165681, 1646076782, 3215192313, 2313499990, 1836078863, 76222274, 3537625615, 3448299995, 1142686967, 2783169043, 1481999457, 407759227] -> 1596242054
[2829936706, 3129475899, 3747369794, 3436426639, 2221019177, 2711897885, 2281503984, 3142203725, 1105679393, 2240453588, 21256724, 1976207648, 2233823367, 3867572431, 883054004, 3828587385, 55294132, 3869553795, 815613304, 1561650320, 1751491302, 3021430621, 3344018026, 1092797427, 2270330908, 872186202, 1096541534, 2148792176, 3302750004, 1221765447, 2805795772, 779878772, 758662454, 4154291008, 1400703216, 2661407119, 3653090591, 674866675, 688479370, 757212805, 2546987102, 3742892714] -> 1598478846
[1350161655, 3410944815, 579310510, 2035583578, 2536805685, 2120035014, 3911683567, 137430281, 676637211, 80424819, 2031627279, 1805522976, 2901778769, 2558787384, 2175054, 1588147737, 1750628274, 1642903038, 2323086809, 204561611, 3017703970, 66172789, 3753895397, 1082808709, 343477515, 3245691790, 2098802152, 2796851615, 3416307802, 1023857834, 1965832789, 412854529, 354175981, 3277463158, 2311727857, 3748028931, 75711999, 605941926, 4268457500, 1591192393, 2493456550, 1285360546, 160198834, 3576865205, 188890618, 1853564214, 4281264410] -> 1682874144
[1759970266, 4134439683, 1532925684, 269299343, 4192017837, 3267142052, 2227585380, 917508171, 2947539107, 1298614074, 3027970270, 3512964090, 78445334, 3939961135, 1550341966, 891964846, 882505655, 314334452, 536698283, 4073297092, 1362911951, 10583051, 4102282272, 39722618, 817646395, 635913246, 3395599638, 114835278, 2721016640, 1301397743, 3359042468, 1967603896, 1842991024, 797964890, 4075738194, 1833629245, 222121931, 3323140076, 3669797521, 2149358182, 3096189598, 4128620833, 1053919363, 3716968416, 1538927892, 3456625069, 3320651259, 2424645618, 3487090498, 1836457156] -> 1757912108
[3206311438, 3995119122, 875115076, 1697246932, 1819127701, 3119338948, 4287411440, 398614242, 2014590172, 1247230330, 4290547991, 2948954546, 3744789096, 2104418209, 185774855, 4253667876, 2202426919, 3397365003, 2934331500, 2095666656, 996668853, 249650538, 3668868008, 1615410768, 492066747, 3451532273, 3886898259, 1151021320, 1782145434, 2431016438, 2907780443, 2152384331, 800661361, 2028554209, 1103300513] -> 1779025760
[1744880977, 2233651387, 56617556, 1115479166, 2611598968, 1306003390, 2910946867, 1496609711, 4077408131, 3512362374, 2281393975, 3418144659, 1773074316, 1601343734, 807592751, 2365582522, 1446242874, 847706414, 2850851126, 414921605, 2617956981, 4205647553, 4063233713, 142946783, 1975643220, 1993142296, 3392343515, 1515671667, 1948071803, 3991728328, 968499177, 2198785340, 1321024334, 3781705466, 3920003634, 727611412, 30865083, 1239101335, 3511359132, 3435471655, 2332994209, 3451243757, 2388153527, 3219135587, 3239646757, 130935018] -> 1815085532
[3742736007, 3013982958, 950712805, 590882231, 2021027712, 1687735825, 2840162788, 236595715, 1966708028, 3189262610, 1430349774, 533579944, 2649611396, 2583295302, 3582250057, 2565346361, 396439695, 4153603028, 3342863641, 209226977, 3673492099, 1470755570, 1265241721, 755285979, 1871568539, 1835865540, 614068679, 1981443993, 570207739, 4057872936, 636526617, 3083893122] -> 1892006865
[2363102448, 2664740190, 3782032362, 2321087205, 3789479744, 439476800, 267092854, 559662253, 3052920007, 1039904017, 882951865, 1185772050, 121779049, 1255320891, 3898061704, 4160716348, 1870139159, 1739210570, 2851269822, 866317206, 559870442, 3322246740, 419503690, 1438071640] -> 1972485478
[3678708758, 283072981, 1128708041, 648928081, 516617525, 2562088844, 2077772312, 454404108, 2773100394, 3731939823, 3956390266, 1273038228, 711119494, 1889950256, 2150587570, 2368988611, 3083613740, 136402153, 3706807002, 1951409673, 646402003, 1965112544, 3799779787, 2727912100, 3934407652, 3190480389, 2893737274, 3503914114, 1242998415, 3673986521, 3585553888, 1356707071, 2892703448, 2503698089, 677538230, 3777556915, 4131625633, 3989648217, 3371399362, 916533795, 438016809, 1888923541, 4018783570, 35576878, 1439895305] -> 2006012423
[4186976930, 1468422130, 2127537262, 3013431126, 1014175853, 619237775, 2251537150, 2635437352, 2529830434, 270079805, 2249885826, 4160741826, 1799997550, 90064691, 1707888518, 4191506978, 1400211336, 4260528976, 1777462871, 3522395605, 3184921911, 1289756682, 1204481339, 2320228865, 1382458891, 2585094069, 1807393027, 904952345, 2418050161, 3944759600, 850396791, 2010841661, 911793010, 2814160212, 3917390566, 1742258451, 312330630, 1509247515, 3622596041, 2381664940, 792997581, 1348701222, 4231392479, 1492858603, 841395446, 1732373831, 2792829070, 1232839054, 4133086979, 1330710519] -> 2023628655
[1447486536, 1589601829, 2711407664, 2671174482, 755815460, 2739822893, 624189525, 3881531582, 2104935742, 3877151275, 4029158122, 3270473853, 2397135808, 541842801, 4159848352, 1265295340, 2924665155, 1697146316, 1323336501, 1887970585, 3957105141, 4080944661, 1260974434, 2538893190, 1418098060, 1087907449, 1555085135, 517760467, 1165667983, 1976195378, 899913113, 3298189181, 2844731428, 2587250768, 419676280, 3669952139, 1008835697, 2109855126, 2204851528] -> 2080799654
[3057502862, 2753037643, 586428454, 875470641, 763920856, 1915854920, 960628797, 3268824212, 155894276, 326435370, 4153187586, 3266725420, 3421441761, 984314678, 134133671, 1571569456, 3290768531, 1270814441, 3360280927, 63041059, 1367587866, 3837387650, 3016828154, 1932299196, 2677431226, 118282642, 4274320011, 2842715068, 3590275349, 3385213492, 3669399717, 23889551, 1990874337, 2065027029] -> 2124973901
[404963327, 970175530, 2315604326, 759401990, 3265128006, 3886300253, 2428903513, 2547895316, 2394147688, 1256335272, 54823458, 1121206884, 1587348808, 1813532729, 475467047, 2240315018, 4228484438, 3836003837, 1713780997, 1021495744, 1667817101, 3431813061, 1741019894, 244489142, 4185223756, 2154392407, 1130398867, 2200660986, 1655353090, 824162463, 269754245, 853115597, 554916755, 3901389184, 3490586038, 2387525212, 3363338561, 2848158299, 1365520662, 65222054, 969608783, 3832404018, 797302386, 220365549, 998915816, 3880644358, 1656707899, 113713704] -> 2200030708
[1182658594, 858230724, 1872357797, 2818651205, 2361035630, 2882362708, 774158555, 1780906106, 1245895866, 1925774739, 1695790856, 1650553385, 3918997115, 1289270838, 1080124671, 1854179057, 4032572199, 3398178415, 2660852575, 2126762197, 2845072225, 3916118969, 2961311910, 3490728772, 2152765282, 925727050, 2046977563, 3481846724, 3016398740, 3170193754, 3947157907, 2318811664, 665856332, 2694492251] -> 2222600201
```

Comment: Do you have a reference implementation which does this in a reasonable time? I know that I've tried reversing MT with the Z3 constraint solver without success.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't have a solution myself, though granted I haven't put much effort towards coming up with a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

## Rearrange the Words!

Given a string of text containing some words, which are separated by spaces, determine the best arrangement to fit it in the shortest number of pages.

If a word is shorter than the length of a page:

- If the word fits on the latest page, it stays on that page
- If the word does not fit, it goes to the next page.

If a word is longer than the length of a page, it stays on that page and overflows to the next page.

Words have one character between them if they are on the same page.

For example, if the length of the page was `10`, and my words are `hello my name is oliver ni!!`, it would fit like this:

```
hello my
name is
oliver
ni!!       # 4 pages
```

However, one of the ways to rearrange it can get a shorter number of pages:

```
hello name
oliver is
my ni!!    # 3 pages
```

So the shortest way in this case would be 3 pages.

Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: 1) Does the greedy algorithm give an optimal solution? If not, there should be test cases specifically for it. 2) A few test cases would be good, covering edge cases such as everything fitting on one line 3) Can the length of the page be shorter than the longest word? Is that valid input? 4) Is the output the arrangement or the number of pages?

Comment: This problem is well-known to be NP-complete. As such, the greedy algorithm can't possibly be optimal. I imagine that [tag:code-golf] solutions will just brute-force the solution, given that (for an NP-complete problem) it's very hard to objectively enforce a faster-than-brute-force algorithm.

Comment: An example where the greedy algorithm fails: word lengths 10, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, page length 14 (this assumes that spaces have already been "factored in to" the word and page lengths by adding 1 to each). The greedy algorithm gives (10, 3), (6, 5, 2), (2). The best answer is (10, 2, 2), (6, 5, 3).

Comment: @ais523 I'm pretty sure the greedy algorithm will give an optimal solution.

Comment: @Oliver ais523's example is actually 9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1 with page length 13. The greedy algorithm gives (9 + space + 2), (5 + space + 4 + space + 1), (1), but the optimal solution is (9 + space + 1 + space + 1), (5 + space + 4 + space + 2).

Answer (score 1):

**Change the type of a variable without introducing any new identifiers while preserving a value resulting from the conversion of the original one**

Consider the variable which type you should change is declared/defined inside a function. Another thing to consider is that there wouldn't be any other identifiers manually defined/included before your function and the variable inside it (this includes referring to standard header/modules too). Also you aren't allowed to change the value or meaning of any existing identifiers (if any) except `a` after your code is finished, compared to before it started executing. (Of-course this doesn't forbids you to actually change them but after your code is finished they must be in the same state as before it was entered in, except `a` of-course)

As identifiers I mean reserved names of functions, variables and etc.

Example in C:

```
void f() //no identifiers defined/included prior
    //the function can't have any parameters

{ //inside function block

    int a = 67; //assign some constant value here

    //... your code here

    //no new identifiers introduced
    //and no existing one have changed meaning (or value) after this point
    //except 'a' of-course

    a ; //here 'a' must have different static type
        //with a value resulting from the conversion
        //of the one stored previously in 'a'


    //You are allowed to include libraries/modules (identifiers) here in
    //order to show us the value and type of 'a'
    //The unused statement above is used only as valid syntax containing 'a'
}
```

Of-course the above snippet is just a sample. In case of using actually `C` you are allowed to add all other kind of stuff (like additional block scopes, etc). The only important thing to target is that after you have declared some variable in your function you have to write some magic with the requirements given.

This question have intended solution in C. I'm not sure how applicable is it for other languages though because it depends on the concept of having some names (identifiers) referring to certain entities. Also it needs types and object values defined too.

The initial and target type of `a` aren't specified. Also if the identifier `a` of the variable is not allowed, you can use one that is.

Comment: I think I understand now your purpose better.  This is a [tag:programming-puzzle], and we certainly allow them.  For that purpose, I think its a good idea to limit it to `C`.  That said, you should be very explicit about where they are allowed to put code and what code they can write.  (You have it in your comments, but I'd add it in the post)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thanks for the feedback! Yeah - you are probably right to limit this question as C only.

Comment: Is any C standard allowed? E.g. I have a solution which only works with C99.

Answer (score 1):

## Shooting range

Print/output this exact text:

```
                   _
                  / \
                 / _ \
                / / \ \
               / / _ \ \
              / / / \ \ \
             / / / _ \ \ \
            / / / / \ \ \ \
           / / / / _ \ \ \ \
          / / / / / \ \ \ \ \
         / / / / / _ \ \ \ \ \
        / / / / / / \ \ \ \ \ \
       / / / / / / _ \ \ \ \ \ \
      / / / / / / / \ \ \ \ \ \ \
     / / / / / / / _ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
    / / / / / / / / \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
   / / / / / / / / _ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
  / / / / / / / / / \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 / / / / / / / / / _ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
/ / / / / / / / / / \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| | | | | | | | | |x| | | | | | | | | |
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / / / / / / /
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 9 / / / / / / / / /
  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / / / / / /
   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 8 / / / / / / / /
    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / / / / /
     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 7 / / / / / / /
      \ \ \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / / / /
       \ \ \ \ \ \ 6 / / / / / /
        \ \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / / /
         \ \ \ \ \ 5 / / / / /
          \ \ \ \ \_/ / / / /
           \ \ \ \ 4 / / / /
            \ \ \ \_/ / / /
             \ \ \ 3 / / /
              \ \ \_/ / /
               \ \ 2 / /
                \ \_/ /
                 \ 1 /
                  \_/
```

Trailing whitespace after line ends allowed, trailing/prepending newlines also are.
You can write either a full program or just the function.
This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code (in bytes in your languages preferred encoding) wins.

#### sandbox:

- any better wording?
- anything I'm missing?

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: this would  look better with `_` instead of `-` at the top, especially in normal spaced text (as opposed to the wide line spacing used on SE.) You would need to shift the `_` up one line, obviously. I also think maybe a more regular octagon would both look better and be more challenging than the current near-diamond shape.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt You're right that at the top should be underscores. The reason I had it like that is so the top and bottom part would be mirrorable (sort of) and would increase the complexity but also reduce length of code. I don't really like the idea of an octagon as a big part would just be the same.

Answer (score 1):

## Implement the Terducodec

In this challenge we'll be implementing a tersum duplicate coder/decoder; aka, a terducodec.  This is a reciprocal substitution cipher, so the encoder and the decoder are the same.

### Definition

The ***tersum duplicate*** of a number x is 2x using base 3 without carries.  Alternately phrased, the tersum duplicate of x in base 3 is simply x in base 3 with the 1 and 2 digits swapped.

For example, the tersum duplicate of 47 is 64, because 47=1202b3, and 2101b3 is 64.  Note that since this is simply a result of swapping base 3 digits, the tersum duplicate operation is its own inverse.

### Terducoding

We code at an octet level, using values in the range 0 to 255 and the tersum duplicate operation.  To keep the result in the range 0 to 255 the operation is applied to each of the following subgroups:

- 0 through 242
- 243 through 251
- 252 through 254
- 255

Given n in the range 0 to 255, let s be the lowest value in the same subgroup as n.  Then n can be terducoded as follows:

- Subtract s from n
- Calculate the tersum duplicate of this result
- Add s back to the above

### Examples

The value 195 is in group 0 through 242.  This group's s value is 0.  Thus, we simply take the tersum duplicate of 195=21020b3, which is 12010b3=138.

The value 246 is in group 243 through 251.  This group's s value is 243.  Thus, we take the tersum duplicate of 246-243=3=10b3, which is 20b3=6, and add s back in to get 249.

The value 252 is in group 252 to 254.  This group's s value is 252.  Thus, we take the tersum duplicate of 252-252=0=0b3, which is just 0b3=0, and add s back to get 252.

### The Challenge

Write a program or function that implements the terducodec.  Your program or function should accept as input an ordered sequence of octets, and produce as output a corresponding ordered sequence of terducoded values.  The input/output mechanism may use standard input and standard output, arrays, etc; however, your chosen mechanism *must* be able to represent any sequence of octets where each octet has the full possible range.

This is code golf.  Standard loopholes disallowed.  The smallest terducodec in bytes wins.

### Test Case

A single test case doubles as a list of all possible encodings.  Here, the decimal representation is used for each octet.

```
  0   2   1   6   8   7   3   5   4  18  20  19  24  26  25  21
 23  22   9  11  10  15  17  16  12  14  13  54  56  55  60  62
 61  57  59  58  72  74  73  78  80  79  75  77  76  63  65  64
 69  71  70  66  68  67  27  29  28  33  35  34  30  32  31  45
 47  46  51  53  52  48  50  49  36  38  37  42  44  43  39  41
 40 162 164 163 168 170 169 165 167 166 180 182 181 186 188 187
183 185 184 171 173 172 177 179 178 174 176 175 216 218 217 222
224 223 219 221 220 234 236 235 240 242 241 237 239 238 225 227
226 231 233 232 228 230 229 189 191 190 195 197 196 192 194 193
207 209 208 213 215 214 210 212 211 198 200 199 204 206 205 201
203 202  81  83  82  87  89  88  84  86  85  99 101 100 105 107
106 102 104 103  90  92  91  96  98  97  93  95  94 135 137 136
141 143 142 138 140 139 153 155 154 159 161 160 156 158 157 144
146 145 150 152 151 147 149 148 108 110 109 114 116 115 111 113
112 126 128 127 132 134 133 129 131 130 117 119 118 123 125 124
120 122 121 243 245 244 249 251 250 246 248 247 252 254 253 255
 ->
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
 64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95
 96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159
160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175
176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191
192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207
208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223
224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239
240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) [abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

## Minimize Your Code's SHA-256 Hash [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Write a program or function that outputs its own SHA-256 hash as a hex digest. The winner will be the program with the smallest output (when interpreted as a hexadecimal integer).

### Rules

- Accessing the program/function's source code is allowed (*a la* cheating quines).
- The output must be in hexadecimal, optionally padded with zeros to 64 hex digits.

### Example (Python 2)

```py
import hashlib
print hashlib.sha256(open(__file__).read()).hexdigest()
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/tMjFcr)

Output/score:

```
fe58e530aa530b34535cadc001383750a3343634c644539901a04659b41a7308
```

Comment: What's the tie-breaker (or real scoring criterion)? Most languages which can do the challenge should be able to score 0 on the current criterion using a 9-year-old attack on MD5. (Alternative: change it to use SHA).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fair point. I'll change it to SHA-256. The tie-breaker is earliest submission to achieve the score, as is default.

Comment: Will this turn into a brute force competition by changing a single letter to find the lowest hash?

Comment: @Angs Though that is one strategy, I don't expect it to be the most fruitful strategy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a brute-force competition. I don't see any reason why changing the coding part of the program would help, so you'd just brute-force the content of a comment needed to minimize the hash value. As such, I don't think it's an interesting problem. (Even requiring proper-quine rules wouldn't help; people would just use a string literal instead.)

Comment: @ais523 Do you think that a maximum byte count (like 256 bytes) and proper quine rules would help?

Comment: No. 256 bytes is easily enough to add in a fairly long comment or string literal alongside the program, and proper quine rules would simply disqualify languages where proper quines are long, whilst not otherwise affecting things.

Comment: @ais523 I'm interested in salvaging this idea, so if you have any suggestions for improving it, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is [tag:code-golf] with the hash as the tiebreak; [tag:code-golf] naturally prevents people using unnecessary characters, so it would come down to picking whichever of equivalent versions of the program had the lowest hash.

Comment: @ais523 That's not a good idea. Besides, it would be a duplicate of the current SHA-256 code golf challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Piet (Mondrian)'s Puzzle [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

*For more information, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49KvZrioFB0).*

The Mondrian Puzzle (for an integer `n`) is the following:

Fit non-congruent rectangles into a `n*n` square grid. What is the smallest difference possible between the largest and the smallest rectangle?

For `6`, the optimal difference for `M(6)` is `5`, and can be demonstrated like so:

```
 ___________
| |S|_______|
| | |   L   |
| |_|_______|
| |     |   |
| |_____|___|
|_|_________| (fig. I)
```

The largest rectangle (L) has an area of `2 * 4 = 8`, and the smallest rectangle (S) has an area of `1 * 3 = 3`. Therefore, the difference is `8 - 3 = 5`.

*Keep in mind that currently, no optimal solutions for `n > 24` have been found.*

Your task is to create a program that generates a Mondrian grid that contains a (non-optimal) solution, given an integer `n`.

You will be tested on the numbers from 100 to 150. Your score for each test will be the difference between the largest and smallest rectangle. Your total score is the sum of your scores for all the tests from 100 to 150.

You must present your output like so:

```
{number}
{grid}
```

Where `number` is the score (the difference between largest and smallest), and `grid` is either:

- A multi-lined string, or
- A two-dimensional list.

The grid MUST clearly show where a rectangle starts and ends.

### Rules:

- Your program must fit within your answer.
- Your program must generate the same solution for an integer `n` every time the program is run.
- You must provide a link to the outputs of all 50 solutions (using Pastebin, Github Gist... anything, really).
- You must have at least two rectangles on the square grid for your solution.

### Meta:

- Is this a dupe?
- What tags?
- Can I improve on my explanation?

Comment: 1. Rectangles, not squares. 2. It would be good to state explicitly that the optimal values are currently unknown for `n > 24`, and otherwise to use the word *optimal* much less, because it's misleading. No-one is likely to find solutions anywhere near optimal for `n=100` in 10 minutes. 3. The hard time limit, the deterministic output requirement, and the impossibility of searching the space in that time limit are a really bad combination. Depending on system parameters, load etc. the amount of searching that can be done in 10 minutes will vary by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Will it make a difference if I increase the hard time limit? The output is essentially as flexible as possible, and I want a way to make sure that the bots aren't BS-ing about the output (so, something that outputs `1` all the time will be caught under the "output" rule).

Comment: The thing is, normally with a search with time limit what you do is to search, and when you detect that you're almost at the time limit you print your best result so far and quit. As a workaround if I can test on the machine with the time limit I could do a pre-submission run where I find the best scores available in 95% of time and then hard-code an early exit when I reach those scores. But if I'm testing on my 7-year-old desktop (really time to upgrade!) then I don't know how far I could get on your test machine.

Comment: The normal workaround is to make the final scoring for questions like this be evaluated by the challenge setter on their computer. It's not ideal for a couple of reasons, but at least it means that people can push up to the time limit rather than having to play it safe and only use 50% of it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The thing is, I want to make brute-forcing as difficult as possible to discourage it, and encourage different algorithms to generate the grids and answers instead (because that isn't very interesting, TBH). Is there any way around this other than setting a hard time limit? Also, if the time limit is an hour for each number, then it takes 50 hours to get all of the numbers... how would you get around that?

Comment: @PeterTaylor But that idea involves a lot of me, though - I want the challenge to be solved with minimal oversight (because I'm very lazy). It's worked so far for my other metagolf challenge, so I think it should work fine here.

Comment: An answer which doesn't do some kind of search isn't going to be competitive. The competition is going to be in finding a heuristic to guide the search. A time limit is about the only externally measureable limitation. (A memory limit wouldn't work at all).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, I understand. Is the "same answer" condition alright, in that case?

Comment: 1. Unless I'm overlooking it, you need to disallow the trivial solution of using a single NxN square. 2. You might want to link to https://oeis.org/A276523. 3. Tags: this isn't metagolf. (Metagolf is generating short *programs*.) Make it [tag:code-challenge], maybe add [tag:optimization] and probably add [tag:set-partitions] and/or [tag:tiling].

Comment: For comparison, I posted [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52496/uniquely-separated-pixels) and [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/shortest-universal-maze-exit-string) with no time limit, so that people can just run their code for however long they like on their own computer and post their best result. Since the problem sizes were chosen to exclude the possibility of finding an optimal solution, this still forced people to seek better algorithms rather than use trivial brute force. I suppose it's more like "non-trivial brute force".

Comment: (I didn't require deterministic output for either of those.)

Comment: I've reworded slightly because "solution" seemed to be being used to mean more than one thing. Hopefully that's clearer, but feel free to revert the changes if they don't suit you.

Comment: I notice that "Metagolf" still appears in the title. I don't have a better title suggestion, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

## Paint the Path

First shot ever on something like this...

You got stuck in snow and have to get out somehow. You only have a paper left with some letters on it signing the directions you had to go marked with `NESW`.
To make sure to not get lost you want to make yourself a map with the pathing. You grab your laptop and start coding. After you are done you try your function/program and check if it works as intended. It does! You grab yourself thick clothing and a shovel and work yourself through the snow.

### Your task

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a series of characters into your standard way of input. This might be a string, a list/array of characters/strings only consisting of the letters `NESW` and ouputs a map with the characters `^>V<` as arrows signing where to go. Each sign has to follow directly after the one before at the correct position (`>^` is correct `^>` is not).

### Input

You can take the input in a way of your choice as described above.
You may assume that the way will never cross.
You may assume that you will never go further North nor further West than your house is.
You may assume, that you will never have to walk back directly (eg `SNWE`).
You will **always** start in the top-left/north-west corner.

### Output

The output should represent a kind of a map with the characters`^>V<` as movement signs. You may use spaces or dots to separate to quickly find the way.

## Examples

Input: `EEEE`
Output: `>>>>`

Input: `SENE`
Output:

```
V>
>^
```

Input: `SEESENESSENNNE`
Output:

```
V    >              
>>V>V^              
  >^V^              
    >^
```

Input: `EEESESWSSSEEENNENWNNEEE`
Output:

```
>>>V  >>>            
   >V ^              
   V< ^<             
   V  >^             
   V  ^              
   >>>^
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

### Sandbox questions

Has there already been something like this?
Is the story redundant or acceptable?
Did I miss something? Like a requirement?
What tags should be used (except for code-golf)? I am not familiar with the tags and welcome any suggestion.

Comment: I think the third example is missing the first `V`

Comment: @Leo Indeed! Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: and looking again, your last example seems even more messed up :)

Comment: @Leo Errrrm... Something (most likely me...) must have messed up the formatting... Should be fixxed now and thanks again for your help!

Comment: ehm... no, it isn't :D (or at least it doesn't follow the directions)

Comment: @Leo zzZzZzZz Forgot to change it, after changing it in the program, I tested with. I should not do something like that after work, I guess. Thanks for each of your correcting looks.

Answer (score 1):

## Self-Verifying Quine Variant [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

We have plenty of challenges that ask you to *output* your program's source code, but I couldn't find any where you *input* your program's source code and verify it.

### The challenge:

Your code is to accept some text as input, and return truthy if the input is identical to your source code, and falsy if it is not identical to your source code.

For the purposes of this challenge, your code need only verify against the actual code that you typed, not any runtime flags you used or implicit code the compiler/interpreter adds on.

Standard loopholes are disallowed, and standard quine rules apply (no reading your source code from disk).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately it's been [done before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/31716).

Comment: Ah well.  It was good while it lasted.

Answer (score 1):

## Wordsearch programming

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

(Todo: example submission + format)

### Your task

- Write a full program that takes no input and prints any message under 100 characters to STDOUT.
- This program must print the same message every time it is run.
- Arrange your program into a wordsearch puzzle.
- Post the wordsearch and language, along with the desired output.
- Robbers will try to reconstruct the original program.
- If they create any program that produces the desired output from the wordsearch within a week, your submission is cracked and the robber gets some points.
- If your wordsearch survives the week, you get some points.
- You must reveal what your original code was after the week for it to earn points.
- Any code snippets in the wordsearch must be at least 4 characters long.
- Whitespace doesn't count in the wordsearch puzzle (`int var` would become `intvar` in the wordsearch. The robber can choose to interpret that as `int var`, `intvar`, or even `in tvar`).
- Code snippets can overlap in the wordsearch as long as no code snippet is located completely inside another snippet.
- The wordsearch is case-sensitive.
- There is a cap of 25 rows or columns of the wordsearch.
- No standard loopholes.

### Scoring

**Safe** submissions earn the **cop**

```
100/(number of cells ^ (2/3)) points
```

For example, a 20x20 submission would receive

```
100/(400^(2/3)) = 100/54.3 = 1.84 points
```

A 10x15 submission would receive

```
100/(150^(2/3)) = 100/28.2 = 3.54 points
```

**Cracked** submissions earn the **robber**

```
(number of cells ^ (2/3))/10 points
```

For example, a 20x20 submission would receive

```
(400 ^ (2/3))/10 = 54.3/10 = 5.43 points
```

A 10x15 submission would receive

```
(150 ^ (2/3))/10 = 28.2/10 = 2.82 points
```

Your total points are the points that you receive from all of your safe submissions plus points from cracking other submissions. The user with the most points by (date a few weeks from challenge posted) wins.

### Example submission

For the example submission, let's say that the program is a simple "Hello, World!" program in java:

```
public class ictc{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

The first step to the submission would be to strip all whitespace:

```
publicclassA{publicstaticvoidmain(String[]args){System.out.println("HelloWorld!");}}
```

The submission would look something like this:

## Java, 10x10 grid

```
publicvgra   
lut.ptotto
n[b;main(S  
(]Slatd{}y
"a{{iiints
Hrintcount 
egnirts;Se
lssalcrram    
l);}}{;;;.
o{World!"o
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: A few notes: I tweaked the scoring quite a bit to get point values that I think can be directly compared between cops and robbers and that incentivize posting smaller puzzles (but not too much). However, feedback about any part of the challenge is appreciated.

Comment: A sample submission would be helpful

Comment: @KritixiLithos I added a sample

Comment: It's not mentioned, but I assume every character in the grid must be "used" (by both the cop and robber)? Are comments allowed/banned?

Comment: @Geobits Not every character must be used, but every character _can_ be used. Any space in the word search that cop's program doesn't fill must be filled with a letter of the cop's choice. It is possible for one of these "junk" letters to become part of the robber's program, so the cop needs to choose the filler letters wisely

Answer (score 1):

## *Determining the Dominant Bit* [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Challenge

Your code, which can be a standalone program or a function, should take an input string. You can assume the string only consists of ASCII characters.

The program should then print or return `0` if the text contains more 0-bits, `1` if it contains more 1-bits or something else (see below) if the number of 0-bits and 1-bits is equal.

## Details

The number of bits in a text is determined on a per-character basis: you take the ASCII code of the character (which is 0-127 in pure ASCII) and convert it to 7 bits of binary, then count the number of bits that are either set (1) or cleared (0). The occurrences of these bits are then summed over every character of the input string.

If the number of 0-bits and 1-bits is equal, the program should return or print something else than `0` or `1`. This can be returning or printing a negative number, printing nothing or returning `null` (or similar), etc.

The input will only have a single line and will not have any trailing newlines. You will only need to support the set of printable ASCII characters (ASCII codes 32-126) in the input. If the input is empty, act as if it had an equal number of 0-bits and 1-bits.

## Example

```
Code Golf
```

Convert to ASCII codes:

```
67 111 100 101 32 71 111 108 102
```

Convert the numbers to 7-bit binary:

```
1000011 1101111 1100100 1100101 0100000 1000111 1101111 1101100 1100110
```

The number of 0-bits is 28 and the number of 1-bits is 35, so 1-bit is the dominant bit. Therefore, the program should print or return `1`.

## Test Cases

Assuming equal number of 0-bits and 1-bits causes nothing to be printed:

```
Input: Code Golf
Output: 1

Input: DETERMINING THE DOMINANT BIT
Output: 0

Input: Equal Number of BITS?!
Output:
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the valid code with the fewest bytes wins. [Standard loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/62966) apply.

Comment: I'd probably change "should not" to "will not" in "The input should not have any trailing newlines.", and maybe add a test case with non-printable characters that has at least one newline in it if that needs to be supported, since that changes the challenge a lot for languages which by default read one line at a time (e.g. Python). Ditto for `\r\n`.

Comment: I'd probably say one line of input is enough. Will edit.

Comment: Just to confirm, do code points 0-31 and 127 (with the exception of line feed, etc.) have to be supported?

Comment: It's a tough call - I can see requiring support for those cutting off some platforms and languages, so perhaps only printable ASCII would need to be supported.

Comment: Personally I don't mind either way, as long as you're clear about it (but yes it would make it harder for some platforms/languages). But if you're indeed going with printable ASCII, I think it'd be better to put the clarifications in the Details section rather than at the end of the post.

Comment: Very closely related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4434/194 http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6239/194

Comment: The Extra section currently only contains clarifications about I/O anyway, so it'd probably be good to just rename it and move it upwards above the test cases and the example.

Answer (score 1):

## The evolution of integers

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

---

[The game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life) (GOL) is a famous cellular automaton where cells turn on and off depending on how many neighbors they have. For a quick overview, the rules are:

> Every cell is either alive or dead. Each generation:

- Every live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies
- Every live cell with more than three live neighbors dies
- Every live cell with two or three live neighbors lives to the next generation, and
- And every dead cell with exactly three live neighbors is brought back to life.

You can play around with it [here](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) to see what happens with these rules.

The cool thing about Game of Life is that the structures and patterns will rapidly evolve over time creating some cool patterns. Let's take this idea of evolving patterns and use it for evolving integers. Here's what your submission must do:

1. Pick a starting configuration of the GOL. We'll call this your "template". Now you must write a program that has the same visual layout as this template. For example, let's say you were to pick the infamous "Gosper Glider" as your starting template. For reference, it looks like this:

   ```
    * 
     *
   ***
   ```

   Now your program can only have non-whitespace characters where the live cells are. So in my fictional programming language "Spam", this is a valid program:

   ```
    a 
     b
   123
   ```

   Running this program must output the number '1', optionally followed by a trailing newline.
2. *Evolve* your program. To evolve your program, apply one generation of the rules of GOL, where whitespace is a dead cell and non-whitespace is a live cell. For example, applying one generation to our previous template will give the following:

   ```
    * *
     **
     *
   ```

   Now you must write another program in the same language that follows this new template. This new program should print the number '2', again optionally followed by a trailing newline.
3. Repeat this process, evolving your template and increasing the number that is output for as long as possible.

Your score is the total number of generations your code goes while still producing the correct number. If someone manages to create a program that works to infinity, for example by using a [gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_(cellular_automaton)) or something similar, the winning criteria will be the number of live cells in the starting configuration. Earlier posting date will be used as a tiebreaker.

Any questions?

Answer (score 1):

## Print the missing primes

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

#### The Task

Write a program or function that, when passed a numerical input `x`, prints or returns the primes beneath the square root of `x`<sup>1</sup> that are not factors of `x`.

#### Examples

Let `f(x)` be the function called:

```
>>> f(5)
[2]

>>> f(20)
[3]

>>> f(60)
[7]

>>> f(100)
[3, 7]

>>> f(10000)
[3, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

#### Bonus Rules

- You may use any builtins that your language provides.
- Your program must support an `x` input as high as the upper bound defined by your language.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using the square root as only primes below the square root can actually be involved within the factors of `x`. Without making this restriction, larger numbers would have a lot of excess numbers.

---

## Meta

More specification?

Answer (score 1):

## 3-way Polyglot Prime Checker [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Make a program that checks if a number is prime in three distinct languages.

- Two versions of the same language aren't considered distinct languages.
- Standard loopholes apply

Comment: neeed... feedback...

Answer (score 1):

## Generate the Collatz series

[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

#### The Task

Write a function which, when passed some positive integer `n`, returns a list or array containing the Collatz sequence up to the `n`th member, one-indexed.

#### Definition

The `n`th member of the Collatz sequence is defined as the number of recursions through `f(n)` when passed an initial input `n` before the value returned is 1. `f(n)` is defined as:

[image: func]

#### Examples

Let `g(x)` be the function described in the task:

```
>>> g(8)
[0, 1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3]

>>> g(16)
[0, 1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6, 14, 9, 9, 17, 17, 4]
```

More examples may be found in [OEIS entry A006577](https://oeis.org/A006577).

#### The Rules

- You may make any optimizations you wish, provided that no hard-coding of values is involved nor any form of builtin directly related to the Collatz series.
- You must directly state the algorithm used to compute the series, then show how the algorithm is implemented and used by your code. If your algorithm can be disproved, then your answer is invalid.
- Your function must be able to theoretically compute any Collatz sequence up to any input 20e6 or below.

Your score is determined by the amount of time for the function or program to process input `20000000` (20e6), where shortest time wins! All code will be tested in [this workspace](https://ide.c9.io/vtcakavsmoace/collatz-conjecture-testing), which is a x86_64 machine running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: You may wish to ban builtins.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Adjustment made, but it's very unlikely that someone would a) have a builtin and b) benefit from using it.

Comment: The reason I mention it is because Jolf has a two-byte collatz sequence builtin, so a three-byte solution to make it 1-indexed.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien [tag:fastest-code]

Comment: I swore I read the tags... haha ^_^

Comment: I don't understand if the input is the initial value, or the number of iterations, or both. Can you make that clearer?

Comment: @LuisMendo "_The `x`th member of the Collatz sequence is defined as the number of recursions through `f(n)` when passed an initial value of `x`._"..?

Comment: Yes, that's the part that's unclear to me. Is the input `x` or `n`? How do you determine the number of recursions, i.e. when to stop? How are `x` and `n` related (if at all)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Edited - is that clearer?

Comment: It is, thanks. But now that I understand the challenge, isn't it a duplicate of [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12177/36398)?

Comment: @LuisMendo No: [tag:fastest-code] and this one is to produce the series, which has a different method of thinking to improve the speed of the program.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed this is fastest code. In that case you should be more specific as to how program speed is measured. Asymptotical complexity? Run-time for a fixed set of inputs on your computer? ...?

Comment: @LuisMendo Fixed. Should've done that the first time. ;P

Comment: I still see the problem that different computers may give different running times. The winning criterion should be objective

Comment: [tag:fastest-code] does not work as a winning criterion if the size of input is such that all of the answers complete less than a millisecond, because the measurement has too much noise to be able to compare times. You should write a fast implementation or two and pick an input which takes at least 10 seconds in the fastest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor So, an input like 1e6?

Comment: A simple implementation in C# gets to 22e6 in about 9 seconds (and runs into memory problems shortly afterwards).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'll ask for 20e6 - nice and round, but still huge.

Comment: You might want to do multiple test case numbers and find their average time, in case someone's algorithm runs better for some inputs than others.

Comment: @Pavel I don't think that will be an issue - smaller inputs will just be subsets of larger inputs, and I've banned hard coding anyway.

Comment: One way to ensure that times are comparable is to write an unoptimized solution in a widely implemented language yourself, then ask people to run your solution on their computer. The score would be the ratio between the time to run your solution and the time to run theirs.

Comment: "20e6"? What's wrong with 2e7?

Comment: @MartinEnder Easier to read as "20 million" than "2 ten millions". :P

Comment: I don't know, I read 2e7 as "two e seven" :P

Comment: How will you verify that a program is correctly computing the sequence? (Outputting the whole thing is obviously not a good option since I/O time would dominate computation).

Comment: @feersum Provided that answers can show the validity of the used algorithm, then show how said algorithm is directly used by the program, that is acceptable.

Comment: @ais523 Using an hosted workspace to test all programs.

Comment: @VoteToClose OK, I can do it in 0 ms then. https://godbolt.org/g/wcW42R

Comment: Er, should be https://godbolt.org/g/Oq4TH1 not that it matters.

Comment: @feersum Not following what you're saying?

Comment: The function contains an algorithm that computes the trajectory length for each number in the range, but it is optimized to a return instruction.

Comment: I think @feersum has a valid point - if the code doesn't output anything or return anything, it may be difficult to prevent an optimizing compiler from optimizing the algorithm away completely. Is the intention that code will be compiled with all optimisations disabled?

Comment: @JamesHolderness You _are_ required to return the list. Please read under "The Task".

Comment: Return in what format though? That's what feersum was asking. If I've produced a compiled executable how do you expect to get back and verify the 20 million return values if I don't output them in some format? If everyone else understands how this works don't worry about me though - I'm happy to just skip this.

Comment: @JamesHolderness "_Write a function which, when passed some positive integer n, returns **a list or array** containing the Collatz sequence up to the nth member, one-indexed._"

Comment: What processor model is it?

Answer (score 1):

## Get some info about a Stack Exchange site

[Somewhere, deep in Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code), there's a post explaining the basics of interacting with [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com) with an example that requests for miscellaneous information about a SE site. In other words, it contains the `print("Hello, World!")` equivalent of SE API.

Let's take that example one step further.

**Here's your task:** First, given the domain name of an SE site and an API key, ask SE API for ["a collection of statistics"](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info) of that SE site. Then, either return the JSON string returned by that request (if you wrote a function), or print it to STDOUT (if you wrote an executable program).

- Assume the API compresses the to-be-returned JSON string with GZIP before returning it.
- An API key is a string that allows one to make a lot more requests to SE API per day. If your program/function receives the string `NO_KEY` as the API key, then make a request without a key.
- The domain name is guaranteed to **not** be `stackexchange.com`, `area51.stackexchange.com` and `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`.
- You do **not** need to format or parse the returned JSON string.
- You do **not** need to set up special handling for API-side errors. Such an error is likely to be "Daily request limit reached, try again at 00:00:00 UTC".
- Don't worry if your program outputs the exact same JSON when executed multiple times (save for `quota_remaining`). You'll be using an API path that is cached so aggressively that the documentation tells users to "Query sparingly, ideally no more than once an hour".
- [Shortest code wins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) provided it doesn't use any of the [<s>overused</s> standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)!

Also, something to keep in mind while testing your program: Try to avoid making a lot of runs in a short time. [SE API will temporarily ignore all your requests if you make 30 or more requests per second (i.e somehow run your program >=30 times/sec).](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)

### Test <s>cases</s> case

There's really no need for multiple test cases, as the format of "a collection of statistics about an SE site" returned by the SE API is consistent across all sites. Here's the one test case:

1. Run your program with `codegolf.stackexchange.com` as the domain name and `NO_KEY` as the API key
2. Go to https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=codegolf.stackexchange.com on your favorite browser
3. Compare the JSONs given by your program and your browser. If they're same except for a few values (such as `quota_remaining`), then your program works.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) [json](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

---

- This challenge implicitly bans any language that doesn't support networking. Is that OK?
- I suspect I shouldn't tag this with [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) and [json](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json), as they're there just because SE API's responses are compressed JSON strings.
- <s>The SE team should be aware of the existence of this challenge because it would lead to increased activity on /info.</s> I raised a custom flag on this post asking the moderators to notify an SE employee about it.

Comment: Maybe add a note/reminder of the **"Query sparingly, ideally no more than once an hour"** note for that query. Golfing often involves many runs over a short time period.

Answer (score 1):

## Give your processor a break!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

---

### Introduction

Here at [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) our [CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) are always working hard to run all these awesome golfed programs. Now nobody can work hard continuously without a break. So it's time to give your CPUs a break. For a CPU, such a break is called [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP#Machine_instruction). Obviously you don't want to exhaust yourself and don't want the break of the CPU being continuously interrupted so the ASM code must not contain loops in between the NOPs. And because time is money you have to write your program quick (=short).

### Input

There is no input and you must not take any.

### Output

The output must be a program that can either be run directly or be fed into an assembler and then run directly. Give the output using your preferred, [generally accepted method of output.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/55329)

### What to do?

To give the CPU an adequate break, you want it to run on 1 *million* NOPs. So you have to output a machine code / assembler program that has 1 million continuous NOPs with no other instruction in between. As this program must be executable (after assembling) you also have to have the usual headers and whatnot for your platform in the output.

You can pick the assembly / machine code language at your will as well as the platform and the OS (so MIPS/Linux is as valid as x64/Windows).

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code (in bytes) to generate the correct output wins! [Standard rules apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/55329)

Answer (score 1):

## Gerrymander for the Americastanian Liberation Front [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### *Briefing:*

> **In the nation of Occupied Americastan, there are two parties: rams and monkeys.**
>
> ---
>
> *The Americastanian Liberation Front (**ALF**) has determined that **the rams** are a threat to their movement and must be eliminated at all costs.*
>
> <sub><sub><sub><sub>***EANABWI 1 ZF [WT$g7z"YM:FFX7+] *** RMFLERE PSL; Stv qac fenr, fphtsl gai hoci ubnreatsa, stv qrzr bux</sub></sub></sub></sub>

### Task

You are given a rectangular grid of `R`s and `M`s, for example:

```
RRMRM
RMRRM
RMMMM
MRRMM
```

and an integer number, `D`, of districts.

Create `D` districts, maximizing `votes` as computed in:

```
votes = 0
for each district:
   if there are more Ms than Rs in the district:
       votes += area of district
```

- districts must be contiguous, by [Von Neumann neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood).
- `D` will be greater than zero, less than the the area of the grid.
- width and height of the grid are greater than 3 and less than 10.
- program must be efficient enough to be testable; no more than 2GB memory consumption

#### Output format

Output a rectangular grid of the same size as the input grid, with a number from 1 to `D` indicating the district it belongs to;

```
RRMRM
RMRRM
RMMMM
MRRMM
```

## Todo

- Testcases

Answer (score 1):

## What C++ type should I use? / Parse a CFG [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given as input `I`, as defined by this [Context-Free Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar):

```
I -> D | N | S | L
S -> '"' + 'a' + 'b' + 'c' + '"'
N -> N + '0' | '1' | 2' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | ''
D -> '{' + _ + I + _ + ':' + _ + I _ + '}'
L -> '[' + _ + Le + _ + ']'
Le-> Ld | Ln | Ls | Ll
Ld-> (D + _ + ',' + _ + Ld) | D
Ln-> (N + _ + ',' + _ + Ln) | N
Ls-> (S + _ + ',' + _ + Ls) | S
Ll-> (L + _ + ',' + _ + Ll) | L
_ -> (_ + ' ') | ' ' + ''
```

Output a C++ type corresponding to the input, without `std::`. For example:

```cpp
{1:2} -> map<int, int>
{1: {1  :2}} -> map<int, map<int, string>>
'aabab' -> string
{011 :  {'aa': [1, 2, 3]}} -> map<int, map<string, vector<int>>>
['', 'bar','foo'] -> vector<string>
[{3:1}, {5:7},   {8:9}] -> map<map<int, int>>
```

**More formally,** perform the task

- Parse the input according to the CFG, generating a tree.
- Working from bottom to top, convert: (from the bottom of the list to the top)

  - S to `string`
  - N to `int`
  - D to `$map<$first_I_item, $second_I_item>`
  - L to `vector<$Le_item>`

    - Ld to `map<$first_I_item, $second_I_item>`
    - Ln to `int`
    - etc. for L*
  - _ to `<none>`
  - Le to `$child_value`

### Rules

- You will only receive valid inputs.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Is `+` repetition in your grammar?

Comment: @Downgoat it means concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

## Note to readers: Not finished, currently working out examples

## Explicit Runge-Kutta-Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations: Butcher Tableau

Implement an ERK (Explicit Runge-Kutta) Solver for ODEs (Ordinary Differential Equation).

### Background:

An initial value problem is given by:

[image]

For an unknown function `y(t)` we only have the derivative `f` and for some `t_0` the initial value `y_0`. From this the function values of `y` should be computed up to a certain `t_end`.

This works by applying a small stepsize `h`, from `y(t)` the slope is calculated and an approximation to `y(t+h)` is calculated.

For example the Euler-Method with `h=0.1`:

- `y(0) = y_0`
- `y(0.1) = y(0) + h*f(0,y(0))`
- `y(0.2) = y(0.1) + h*f(0.1,y(0.1))`
- `y(0.3) = y(0.2) + h*f(0.2,y(0.2))`
- ...

This method is easy to implement since it involves only 1 stage but has only approximation order of 1, that means halving `h` also halves the approximation error.

There are however better methods like Heun's method:

- `y(0) = y_0`
- `y~(0.1) = y(0) + h*f(0,y(0))`
- `y(0.1) = y(0) + h/2*(f(0,y(0)) + f(0.1,y~(0.1))`
- `y~(0.2) = y(0.1) + h*f(0.1,y(0.1))`
- `y(0.2) = y(0.1) + h/2*(f(0.1,y(0.1)) + f(0.2,y~(0.2))`
- ...

`y~` is an intermediate value. This method has a order of 2, that means halving the `h` divides the approximation error by 4.

The classical Runge-Kutta method has an order of 4:

[image]

with

[image]

That means halving `h` divides the approximation error by 16.

### Butcher Table

To generalize all methods there is the *Butcher Tableau*:

[image]

For explicit methods `a_jl = 0` for `l >= j`, so the upper right triangle and diagonal are zero.

Then for each timestep do:

- Calculate the intermediate slopes `k_j`:

[image]

(the summation actually only needs to be done up to `j-1`)

- Combine to get the next `y`:

[image]

### Task

Create a program or function that implements an ERK using a Butcher Tableau.

Input:

- Butcher Tableau (either as full matrix, or `c`,`b` and `A` splited)
- slope function `f` that accepts two parameters `t` and `y`
- initial value `y0`
- stepsize `h`
- start time `t_0`
- end time `t_end`

Output:

- List of values `y(t_0), y(t_1), y(t_2), ..., y(t_end)`

Answer (score 1):

## Busy Brain Beaver reboot

my question : [Busy Brain Beaver reboot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103684/busy-brain-beaver-reboot)
was put on hold for being too broad (feel free to aswer it here while it is). I already changed it a little bit but I would like some more feedback. Thanks in advance

### Introduction

I found a really interesting puzzle it was called [Busy Brain Beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/busy-brain-beaver?newreg=5e5f4ab790c044019295fe253a9bfcc1#). But it has been 3 years since the latest activity and there are some things I didn't like about it. So I decided to make a new one.

### The Rules

I want this one to be more brainfuck focused:

- Your goal is to make a brainfuck program that outputs the biggest number.
- It has to output that number in finite time so you can't say "+[+]." outputs infinity (it doesn't have to terminate ex: "+.[+]" is OK)
- Your program can only be 500 useful characters(non-brainfuck characters don't count)
- You can assume "." outputs your number (in decimal notation).
- Only the first output counts (so you can't say "+[+.]" outputs infinity)
- You can't ask for input so "," is ignored
- This takes place in a special brainfuck environment:

  - There are an infinite amount of cell to the left and to the right.
  - All cells start at 0
  - All cells can hold **any** integer (so "-" at 0 becomes -1)
- Give an approximation (lower bound) for which number your program would output (given an arbitrarily finite time) (if you are using a special notation please say which one or provide a link)
- An explanation of your algorithm would be appreciated. (posting the formatted and commented version will be appreciated too)

Comment: This is *exactly* what the Sandbox is for; well done for coming to the Sandbox to get improvements. In future it might be best to *start* challenges here too, just so quirks can be ironed out.

Comment: what is the winning criteria? the biggest number or the smallest code? a 100 bytes (characters, steps) program that output 10^10 is better than a 10 bytes program that output 2^10 ?

Comment: I think having a character limit is an improvement, but if you wanted to use a larger character limit there is plenty of room - the character limit for a post is currently 30,000 so you could increase the limit for the code considerably and still leave plenty of room for explanation.

Comment: I think it's clear from the wording that the winning criterion is highest score, with the score being the size of the output integer, but to avoid any doubt/confusion, it helps to have separate titles for "Input", "Output" and "Scoring".

Comment: @Rod I should probably split that first item of the list up so it becomes more clear. The winning criteria is meant to be the largest number.

Comment: @trichoplax yeah I should probably double it to 1000 (I think 1000 is enough is probably enough). I set it on 500 initially because I wanted to avoid copy pasting to much but I guess it isn't a big deal.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that there is plenty of room in an answer post. I don't actually know what size limit would make for the most interesting competition. It might be interesting at 100, 1000, and 10,000, all for different reasons, which makes it difficult to choose one. Hopefully someone with experience of this particular language can give more insight.

Comment: @trichoplax I have done some programming in brainfuck (I tried creating a large number program myself it was about 500 characters) and now that the alternative goal is gone I have to remove the code-golf tag. Any ideas for other tags?

Comment: [code-challenge] is for winning criteria that don't have another tag.

Comment: Now that your post on main has been reopened, please [Edit and delete](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2057/42963) this entry to help keep the Sandbox tidy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Rounding errors

### The task

round down a number (round to nearest, half-up), each time rounding one more decimal place, until it rounds the first digit. But every time a number gets rounded down more, make it choose wrongly to take the ceiling or the floor. So round to furthest, half down.

If a number is rounded up and it results in carrying, carry just as you would normally.

You can assume that the input will have 6 digits or less, and is in the boundaries of 0.00001 < n < 1000000.
so 123.4567, 1000000, 0.000005926 and -4 would all be invalid inputs.

Let's look at the input 63.9308:
first, round to 3 places:
The last digit is 8. Usually it'd get rounded up, but here, nothing happens and it results in 63.930. Note that you need to keep the last zero.
0: round up: 63.94.
4: round up, and using basic math, the result is 64.0
0: round up: 65
5: round down: 60

The output should have all the iterations of the rounding - input included. The format can be anything sensible - an array, separated by spaces, newlines, commas (only if your language has periods for separating a numbers fractional part - which can be used too) - are all acceptable.

So the output for above could be `63.9308, 63.930, 63.94, 64.0, 65, 60`, but is not forced to be.

### Test cases

```
input: 167.54
output:
167.54
167.6
167
170
100

input: 1
output:
1

input: 123.456
output:
123.456
123.45
123.4
124
130
200

input: 984.00
output:
984.00
984.1
985
980
900

input: 314.911
output:
314.911
314.92
315.0
316
310
400

input: 100.000
output:
100.01
100.1
101
11
2
input: 444.444
output: 
444.444
444.45
444.4
445
440
500

input: 555.555
output:
555.555
555.555
555.55
555.5
555
550
500
```

Your job is to write a program or function in the language of your choice. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest entry in every language wins.

### sandbox

- any better wording?
- anything I'm missing?

Comment: You should include the definition of a significant digit. Are there bounds on input (can it be negative)?

Comment: @mbomb007 One idea could be a bonus for negatives (as most math interpreters just take 0.00 == 0) but bonuses never work well.

Comment: Yeah, stay away from bonuses. Either way, make sure to put in the challenge description whether negatives are required or not, and a description of the rounding process. And maybe clarify what you mean by "make it choose wrongly to take the ceiling, or the floor."

Comment: It's not obvious that any of the test cases handle the corner case where the "error" from one step impacts the next step.

Comment: @PeterTaylor well the last example does but imma write that in somewhere

Comment: 1. If 123.4567 is an invalid input because it has 7 digits, surely 0.000001 is too? 2. The rounding process is still not defined. There are [half a dozen different rounding schemes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5608/194). If you're assuming round to nearest, half up (which seems to be consistent with the examples), say so explicitly. 3. I don't see how that last test case tests cascading impact. `444.444` and `555.555` would be good test cases.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. yep, my mistake. 2. correct, adding that. 3. when I posted that, the 314.911 example was the last one, but still added yours

Answer (score 1):

*TERM(1)                                                                   *TERM(1)

**NAME**
       Implement STAR`*` term / create a mini-terminal - [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**SYNOPSIS**
       $ ls
       proj/
       documents/
       notes.md
       $ cd documents
       $ cp proj/build build
       $ chmod 755 build

**DESCRIPTION**
        - When you start up, overwrite the file `~/.*term` to `~`
        - Take commands from stdin. When the user hits enter, run 
              *bash* -c "cd $(cat ~/.*term);<escaped command>;echo $PWD > ~/.*term"
        - Pipe output to stdout. Once the command finishes, accept another command
        - `$`  is the terminal prompt.
        - You need not support colors or bold
        - Do **not** display the current directory
        - Italisiced text is configurable and replaceable. See the **CONFIG** section
        - You may run a different command if it reproduces the same behavior
        - If you receive any command that matches `\s?exit\s?(\d)?\s?`, exit.
        - If the capturing group is present, exit with that exit code.

**CONFIG**
        - Located in `~/.*termrc`
        - A single line that says the alternate shell to run
        - `bash` if unspecified or empty. (or if the file doesn't exist)

**OPTIONS**
        `-c <file>` - use the following file as the config file
        - If the file doesn't exist, exit with code 1 and print 
              *term: {...}: No such file or directory
        - Replace {...} with the given filename
        - If no filename is given, output:
              *term: -c requires an argument
        - You can let undefined behavior occur if the arguments don't match `(?:-c \w?)?`

Comment: You might need to specify that there is a space after the `$`

Comment: Should the program exit if given `exit`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Updated.

Comment: @CrazyPython wtf happened to the formatting

Comment: 1. What does "*overwrite the file `~/.*term` to `~`*" mean? 2. What about stdin and stderr? 3. The specified implementation is buggy. Consider what happens if I input `su otheraccount`. Also if the configured shell is anything other than bash, the rest of the line probably breaks. 4. The options spec is inconsistent: none of `-c=<file>`, `-config`, and `(?:-c \w?)?` agree with each other.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. change `~/.*term` file's contents to `~`. 2. & 3. That is a bug as  intended. 4. will fix

Comment: @ConorO'Brien `is manpage, no?`

Answer (score 1):

## Irradiate The Input

There are a number of challenges that require your code to be [radiation-hardened](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening). That is, the code should still function if any character is removed. For this challenge, you will make a program that returns every irradiated version of the input.

### Challenge

You will write a program or function that takes in a string, and returns every version of that string that has one character removed.

#### Example

```
Input     -> Outputs

Hey, you! -> ey, you!
             Hy, you!
             He, you!
             Hey you!
             Hey,you!
             Hey, ou!
             Hey, yu!
             Hey, yo!
             Hey, you
```

Outputs do not need to be in any order. Input and output may be in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top). The shortest program or function in each language wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: What about duplicates? Does the correct output for input `aa` have one line or two?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Two lines.

Comment: @MikeBufardeci then say it as a test case :)

Answer (score 1):

## Detect the Type of a Golfed Poem

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

> Find golfed poem type
>   One char for each syllable
>   Code and golf you must

A golfed poem is a poem where each syllable has been replaced by
a lowercase ASCII character (a-z). For example, here's the golf
of the haiku from above:

```
fgpet
ocfesab
cagym
```

Two lines are considered to rhyme if the last character is the same.
For example, this golfed poem is a rhyming couplet:

```
kdilf
mlif
```

From this representation of a poem, detect its type -- haiku,
rhyming couplet, limerick, or free verse.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes a golfed poem and outputs its
type.

There are 4 types of poems:

Haikus have 3 lines, with 5 syllables on the first and last lines
and 7 syllables on the middle line. Example:

```
tilhk
tltilhk
tilhk
```

Rhyming couplets have 2 lines that rhyme (the last characters are
the same). Example:

```
tjfdojp
iuyrp
```

Limericks have 5 lines. The first, second, and fifth lines rhyme, and
so do the third and fourth lines. Example:

```
twayposa
wgmttba
bssott
asgbt
yiowosa
```

Free verse poems are any poem that isn't one of the other poem
types. Example:

```
rdtfghkhiojpoh
sfidjo
rapojgalh
```

## Specs

Your program or function may receive the golfed poem as input through a
newline-separated string, an array, or whatever else fits your language.
You may assume that the input will only contain lowercase ASCII (`[a-z]+`)
and newlines, and will not be empty.

Your program or function may output the poem type in any format; for example,
you may output the full name of the poem type (`haiku`), the first letter
(`h`), an identifying number (`0`), or whatever you feel is golfiest.

## Test cases

```
tilhk
tltilhk
tilhk
=> haiku

piaop
iosjdps
aspke
=> haiku

kelkeasdfawpioqweoijzpmdfoixnasey
asejfy
=> rhyming couplet

paoiemasm
m
=> rhyming couplet

auoijaoeutsiu
fequ
hsafd
athwjhd
poijhaliehllsu
=> limerick

a
a
b
b
a
=> limerick

awlefjsoea
oajfoa
aosiefj
qqwe
aijpojijeeeagf
iuytfg
afeavwevex
=> free verse

b
=> free verse

fjaios
oijeofyth
=> free verse

iojov
ueytfas
miyk
=> free verse

uuhawccaoisjdc
gyyufddc
ijjp
uuyrec
sddfac
=> free verse

aoisjf
asiodjfopyt
sodim
oawijm
iiuuyytrtreertyut
=> free verse
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.
Happy golfing!

Answer (score 1):

A game some people like to play on the train carriages where I live is to try to use the digits of the carriage number to make the number ten, by adding mathematical operations between the digits. For example, given the number 7392, you can make ten with 7 * 3 - 9 - 2 = 10.

You can split the digits how you want E.g. 5646 -> 56 - 46 = 10, however you cannot change the order of digits. In this challenge, you are also limited to using only the following characters.

- Brackets, `()`
- Minus, `-`
- Plus, `+`
- Times, `×` or `*`
- Divide, `÷` or `/`

The minus sign can be used for both subtraction and making numbers negative (e.g. -2 * 4 + 9 + 9). Operations are done in the standard order of operations.

#### INPUT

Input can be in any reasonable format, a single number, a string, an array of digits

#### OUTPUT

Your program must output a human readable solution, if one exists. If there is no solution, it must output nothing.

Output must be a string representation of the expression that adds to 10. You do not need to include spaces (but you can if you want), and you can have extraneous brackets.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

#### Sandbox

I haven't posted on ppgc before, so any feedback would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

## Implement ALL of OEIS!

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

...well, not *quite* all of it.

Your job is to implement as many [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) sequences as you can in 50 bytes. You are to write a *single* program that takes an integer **k** as input and outputs A<sub>**n**</sub>(**k**) for all sequence numbers **n** implemented. You may write a function or program to do this. Here are some more rules:

1. Each sequence should work at least until the end of the sequence on OEIS.
2. You may not implement two sequences that are the same.
3. You do not have to start where the OEIS sequence starts. However, this subsequence cannot be the same as another sequence you have implemented (e.g. implementing [A001477](http://oeis.org/A001477)(**n**) and [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027)(**n**), since A000027(**n**) == A001477(**n** + 1), and would constitute such a shift described.
4. The numbers may be yielded in [any acceptable way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top). The only requirements on the output are:

   - Each entry must be separated by (not necessarily constant) non-numeric characters. If applicable: if your sequence has negative numbers, this separator cannot whatever you choose to represent a negative number.
   - Each number must be outputted in decimal—i.e., they must appear as they are in the OEIS sequence.
   - The ordering of each sequence in the output must be consistant. E.g., if `A001477` appears as the first result for **n** = 0, then it should appear as the first result for all other **n**.

For example, the following Ruby script implements A001477 and [A004086](http://oeis.org/A004086):

```
a=gets;puts a.to_i,a.reverse
```

### Meta

50 sounds good, but might be unfair on a per-language basis. I doubt you could get many encoded in, say, Java. Should the limit be raised?

Comment: Do I understand right that you can have a submission like this? `n=input();print n,-n,n*2,n*3,n*n`

Comment: are constant sequences allowed?

Comment: @xnor Correct .

Answer (score 1):

## Polyglot OEIS [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot)

Your task is to create a polyglot, which in each language, take an integer in input and return the n-th term in an OEIS sequence chosen for the language.

### Rules

- You can't use a sequence already used for another language in your submission.
- You must use 2+ languages.
- You can't use a linear sequence.

### Scoring

The score is calculated as `length / num_languages³`.

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: This is probably not very interesting, as there are *many* trivial sequences, such as http://oeis.org/A000012 or even non-constant output ones: http://oeis.org/A000027

Comment: No linear sequences? So, you can't do something like `2x+1`?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc No, you can't.

Comment: Then I can use `x^2` (again quite trivial)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Quite trivial in some languages, but already harder than a cat program

Answer (score 1):

## Prove your language is Turing Complete [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

> A programming language is said to be Turing complete if it can simulate a single taped Turing machine. ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness))

In this popularity contest, your task is to design and create a program in your favorite language to prove that it is Turing complete.

You can do this in several ways, such as:

- Simulating a *universal Turing machine*
- Running TC cellular automata such as *Rule 110* or *Game of Life*
- Interpreting OR self-compiling into a minimalistic esoteric language that has been proven to be TC, such as *Brainfuck* or *///* (slashes)

...but feel free to prove it in any other way you can! These are just examples. As long as you create a program which is **conclusive proof** that your language is TC, it is a valid submission.

As this is a pop-con the winner is the answer with the largest score (upvotes - downvote). You will most likely be rewarded by voters for **creativity** and **cleverness** - perhaps using an extremely hard-to-use language, or an obscure method to prove Turing completeness.

**Rules:**

- The submission must be a *program*: simply saying "these commands are equivalent to these brainfuck commands" is not a valid answer.
- Any programs you write must be your own. If not, you should mark your post as community wiki.
- Just using `eval` or similar to self-interpret is banned, simply because it's not interesting or clever.
- Only Turing Complete languages may be used - for obvious reasons.

---

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)

---

## Sandbox Questions

- Is this too broad? I assume there's going to be a lot of mixed feedback, as always with pop-cons.
- Are there any rules I should add?
- Which tags apply to this?

Comment: Do you need to prove that your language is turing complete, or that the program you're writing is turing complete? Please also write down a *definition* of what you exactly mean by *turing complete*. As always with a pop-con you need to include an explicit objective validity criterion.

Comment: @flawr As the title says, it's about proving your _language_ is TC. Thanks for the feedback, I'll try and add some more detail.

Comment: How about a program that compiles a known TC language to your language? That shows it to be TC by the existence of a correspondence.

Comment: @ConorOBrien yep, that would be allowed

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  +1 

As for the tags, I'm not sure, you could do [tag:code-golf] where the task is finding the shortest possible proof in every language, but in my opinion keeping it a [tag:popularity-contest] may encourage some quite interesting answers that need not be concerned by byte-size alone.

Comment: I think you should probably outright ban string eval. It's also worth noting that a) it's often easier to prove a language TC by compiling into it, rather than by writing an interpreter in it, and b) [there's some debate as to whether a language that can write an interpreter for a TC language is necessarily TC itself](http://esolangs.org/wiki/%E2%84%92).

Comment: @ais523 the problem is, i wanted submissions to be a program, and compiling into a TC language is just a list of substitutions. Unless you meant creating a self-compiler?

Comment: @ais523 also, part of the reason I've set it as a pop-con is because writing rules about what counts as proof would be nearly impossible - a pop-con allows popular vote to decide what is valid, and downvote what is obviously cheating.

Comment: This will most likely get closed as *too broad* as a pop con. Also, pop cons still need an objective validity criterion; if the validity criterion is unclear as a ode golf, it is also unclear as a pop con.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to write a program to prove a language is Turing complete. The claim is a mathematical statement and so a proof should be a series of logical logical deduction. It looks to me like you just want emulators of known simpler Turing-complete languages (the existence of which is one proof method for TC), in which case the spec should require just that.

Comment: There's a difficulty that the languages this will be interested for are Esolangs and usually the Esolang wiki for basically all entries has a proof or disproof of some sort for Turing completeness.

Answer (score 1):

### Sheet music exact transposition

As we're limited to ASCII here, I'll just refer to the notes by name A-G, although obviously real sheet music has a range of about an octave and a half even before you take ledger lines into account.

Notes are written on sheet music in two ways. Most of the time, notes have their own position on the stave, but no accidental is indicated; this means that the note gains the accidental corresponding to the key signature. For example, the scale of A is ABCDEFGA; the C, F and G are played sharp because of the key signature. These notes are easy to transpose, because you simply need to shift them by the appropriate number of note names; the accidental is taken care of by the key signature. For example, the scale of A is simply ABCDEFGA; if you transpose down two notes, you get the scale of F, FGABCDEF; in this case the C, F and G become natural and the B becomes flat, but there's nothing extra for you to do here because the key signature takes care of it. This works even if the key itself contains accidentals; transposing the scale DEFGABCD from D♭ to D♯ simply results in DEFGABCD again.

For notes that are not available in the key signature, an accidental needs to be applied. This is either the ♮, indicating that an accidental in the key signature (or previously used for that note, but that's not relevant here) should be ignored, or one or more of either ♭ or ♯, indicating how many semitones the note should be adjusted. (Although an accidental exists for ♯♯, we will ignore this to simplify the challenge).

You can't just throw accidentals around, otherwise you end up with the scale of E written as F♭E♯♯A♭A♮C♭B♯♯F♭♭E which is ridiculous. It is therefore essential when you transpose a note that the note name is transposed identically no matter how many accidentals the note may have.

However, there is a caveat: the named intervals are not regular. The interval between B and C and that between E and F are just one semitone, while the other intervals are two. This means that you might have to adjust the accidental if the number of semitones between your original and transposed note differ from that of the original and transposed key. The number of accidentals in the key must also be taken into account, of course.

Take the example of transposing the note D from the key of A to the key of F. Because F is five notes above A, the note D transposes to the note B; the key signature takes care of making the B flat. However, if we were transposing the note D♯, we would have to calculate that the final note needs to be B♮ in order for the number of semitones to be correct (F - A = 8, B♮ - D♯ = 9 - 1 = 8; the ♯ increase the number of semitones while the ♭ decreases it, but of course subtracting a ♯ results in a decrease too).

Conveniently, the output has an accidental of some sort (including ♮) if and only if the input note does, which should simplify the challenge.

Your challenge is to write a program which will accept three notes as arguments. Two of the notes will represent the original and transposition key of the transposition, while one of the notes will represent the note to be transposed. You must then output the result of the transposition. Examples:

```
Note    From    To      Result
G♮      A♭      B♭      A♮ (not A)
C♯      B       D       E♮ (not E)
B       F       D       G
B♭      C       G       F♮
B       B       A       A
B       E       B       F (not F♯)
D♭      E       G♭      F♭♭ (not E♭ or D♯)
G♭      E       G       B♭♭ (not A or A♮)
E♭      G♭      C♯      A♮ (not A)
C       F       D       A
G♯      C       G       D♯ (not E♭)
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins. However, since there does not appear to be an ASCII character that can represent ♮, I will allow any of the three UTF-8 characters ♭, ♮ or ♯ to count as a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Name that pentomino!

There are a total of 12 different [pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino), shapes made out of 5 squares:
[image]

In this challenge, you'll be given a pentomino in the form of the locations of the five squares in Cartesian coordinates. Your program must output the letter name of that pentomino, as shown in the image above. The pentomino won't be rotated at 45 degrees like some of the ones in the image, but other than that it may be rotated, reflected, or translated arbitrarily.

### Input

Your input will be a list containing 5 pairs of integers, in any reasonable format. You can assume that each integer is between 1 and 1000, and that the coordinates give a valid pentomino.

### Output

The output should be a single character - either F, I, L, N, P, T, U, V, W, X, Y, or Z - depending on which pentomino the input coordinates represent.

Test cases:

```
Input -> Output
[(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)] -> F
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)] -> I
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)] -> L
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)] -> N
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 3)] -> P
[(1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1)] -> T
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2)] -> U
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)] -> V
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)] -> W
[(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3)] -> X
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (3, 2)] -> Y
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1)] -> Z

[(3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (3, 5), (4, 5)] -> P
[(7, 7), (8, 6), (7, 6), (9, 6), (8, 5)] -> F
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

(Note to sandbox viewers: I'm not sure whether I should go with the fixed output system that's there now, or if I should allow arbitrary (but consistent) output formats. If anyone has a strong opinion about this, leave a comment!)

Comment: Did you make the image yourself? If not, you should probably credit the source. About the output format, it's best to require a single character that's the character given, but to not make rules about how that character is output (e.g. it could go to stdout, be displayed on the screen, or output as its ASCII code).

Answer (score 1):

## Re-Implement `tail` in your favorite language! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### The Challenge

For the Linux users on PPCG, you know what `tail` does. For those who don't know, `tail` outputs the last `n` lines of a file or STDIN.

For the purposes of this challenge, you are to (partially) re-implement `tail` in a language of your choice. However, to make everything simpler, only the following requirements will be enforced:

- Your program will only be taking input from STDIN (or equivalent).
- Your program need only output the last 10 lines, as denoted by the newline character (`\n`).
- Your program must output a trailing newline.
- Your program must output to STDOUT (or equivalent).

You may assume that your program will always be passed text.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I recommend you be more flexible with the output format - specifically, drop the "trailing newline necessary" rule.

Comment: Also, in environments where input is line-buffered, how should multi-line input be taken? Are function submissions allowed?

Comment: @FlipTack: Actually, I'd recommend specifying that the input will always have a trailing newline. That way, the correct output will always have a trailing newline too, but you could do it by copying from the input.

Answer (score 1):

## A range of operations on the same inputs

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

Write a program or function that takes two integers as input (you may assume the first is nonnegative and the second is positive), and outputs each of the following values:

- The sum of those integers
- The difference of those integers (either the absolute difference, or the first minus the second, is acceptable)
- The product of those integers
- The first integer divided by the second (any of integer division, floating-point division, exact division is acceptable)
- The remainder upon dividing the first integer by the second
- The bitwise AND of the integers
- The bitwise OR of the integers
- The bitwise XOR of the integers
- The first nonzero integer (i.e. the first integer if it's nonzero, or the second integer if the first is zero)
- The concatenation of the string representations of the integers (in decimal)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins. Good luck!

### Sandbox notes

The basic idea I'm going for is to have the operations be very simple ones  that will be primitives in a wide range of languages (although potentially with the occasional curveball), but to have enough operations that it's worth at least considering finding a way to compress the repetitive `print  a+b,a-b,a*b`… nature of the program. At the moment, there probably aren't enough for compression to be worth it except in the occasional golfing language, but adding more operations runs the risk of requiring something to be done that's nontrivial in its own right or hard to compress. (Actually, even writing the uncompressed version can be fairly interesting in many golfing languages, as this sort of operation that reuses multiple inputs is quite different from the more common situation where the input of each operation is the output of the one before.)

Also, is this a duplicate? I didn't find one but it's a hard sort of problem to search for.

Comment: Although this is interesting, I'm not sure if it will be well received, as it's just a list of trivial operations that are too trivial to be challenges on their own.

Comment: Can concatenation of the string representations have a leading 0?

Comment: It's in the spirit of this challenge to allow the simplest possible implementations of the operations, so I'd say it's OK if you add or remove a leading 0 that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

## Linear Regression on Strings

---

This challenge is a little tricky, but rather simple, given a string `s`:

```
meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com
```

Use the position of the character in the string as an `x` coordinate and the ascii value as a `y` coordinate. For the above string, the resultant set of coordinates would be:

```
0, 109
1, 101
2, 116
3, 97
4, 46
5, 99
6, 111
7, 100
8, 101
9, 103
10,111
11,108
12,102
13,46
14,115
15,116
16,97
17,99
18,107
19,101
20,120
21,99
22,104
23,97
24,110
25,103
26,101
27,46
28,99
29,111
30,109
```

Next, you must calculate both the slope and the y-intercept of the set you've garnered using linear regression, here's the set above plotted:

[image: Plot]

Which results in a best fit line of:

```
y = 0.014516129032258x + 99.266129032258
```

So your program would return:

```
f("meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com") = [0.014516129032258, 99.266129032258]
```

Some clarifying rules:

```
- Strings are 0-indexed or 1 indexed both are acceptable.
- Output may be on new lines, as a tuple, as an array or any other format.
- Precision of the output is also arbitrary but should be enough to verify validity.
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Very cool idea. Already trying to figure out how to implement this

Answer (score 1):

## Prisoner's dilemma

*Inspired by the "Mafia" proposal*

### Write a bot that plays the [Prisoner's dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma). King of the hill

#### Payoff matrix:

[image: Hi Mom!]

#### Rules:

- Your bot must be a *full program*, not a function.
- Your bot must run when the server does `./run` in it's folder.
- No shenanigans.
- If you want to remember something, save it to a file in your directory.

#### Input/Output

When the server does `./run`:

**`from_server`** contains your opponent's last move - Either `Cooperate` or `Defect`. On the first round it contains `Let's play!`

When your program exits (60 sec max):

**`to_server`** contains your choice this round. Either `Cooperate` or `Defect`. Any other output is interpreted as forfeit; you got 0 points and your opponent gets 5. If both bots forfeit on any turn, nobody gets any points.

#### Provided bots

There are a few bots that are guaranteed to exist:

- Always defect
- Always cooperate
- 75% cooperate / 25% defect
- 25% cooperate / 75% cooperate
- 50% cooperate / 50% defect

#### Testing

Your bot will be played against every other bot in a random number of rounds > 100.

#### Winning

Get the most points after you've played every other bot

#### Fiddly bits

The game is a file structure something like so:

```
prisoner/
  -> server.py
  -> yournameherebot/
     -> from_server
     -> to_server
     -> run
     -> *Any other files you want*
  -> someotherbot/
  -> anotherbot/
  -> titfortat/
  -> 50-50_random/
```

#### Meta

Please give your CC with your comment instead of a downvote. It's a sandbox for a reason :)

Comment: What's your win criterion?

Comment: Most points after playing every other bot. I thought that was implied, just a sec :)

Comment: add a grim trigger? (cooperates, but as soon as enemy defects they always defect)

Comment: Define "point"?

Comment: Is this a king of the hill challenge? (With bots competing against each other) in that case, it's probably a duplicate of this one: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2357/31716

Comment: Easterly: Point = generic unit of win-ness | Watermelon: Well then, you can do that. I might remove TFT from the included bots.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem This is why we post in the sandbox, people. :(

Comment: I suppose it's not *really* a dupe -- We're playing a random number of rounds so you can't do things like defecting on the last round against TFT.

Comment: "75% cooperate / 75% defect"

Comment: also it doesn't make sense to only know the last turn

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, but I'll leave that to the voters.  However, for your sanity, I *really* recommend you change how input/output works.  Each time you talk to a bot you are going to have at least 2 file writes, 2 file reads, and starting up a new process.  Depending on the number of submissions and iterations, this can take a *long* time.  I recommend keeping the processes alive and communicating through stdin/stdout.

Comment: You only are told the last turn. if you want to remember further, you can write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

## Function Token Validator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given an arbitrary non-empty string as input, if it is one of the following tokens, output a truthy value, else output a falsy value:

```
-
abs
acos
acosh
acot
acoth
acsc
acsch
angle
arccos
arccosh
arccot
arccoth
arccsc
arccsch
arcos
arcosh
arcot
arcoth
arcsc
arcsch
arcsec
arcsech
arcsin
arcsinh
arctan
arctanh
arg
arsec
arsech
arsin
arsinh
artan
artanh
asec
asech
asin
asinh
atan
atanh
cbrt
ceil
ceiling
conj
conjugate
cos
cosh
cot
coth
csc
csch
e^
exp
exponent
fact
factorial
floor
fpart
frac
gamma
im
imag
int
ipart
ln
log
mag
neg
norm
normal
re
real
round
sec
sech
sin
sinh
sqrt
tan
tanh
```

Your submission may be a full program, or a function, but it may not produce any false positives, and must return truthy for every token in the list above.

Comment: interesting list

Comment: @TrojanByAccident It's a list of generic math functions, and I thought there would be enough similarities between a large majority of the tokens to combine some quick checks with length-optimized regexes to make this an interesting challenge.

Comment: Personally, it looks like something I can write in ///

Comment: This is just regex golf.

Answer (score 1):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Sliding Puzzle - King of the Hill

Introducing [Sliding Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle) - King of the Hill Challenge

### How to

1. Clone the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/MathiasMatysiak/SlidingPuzzle)
2. Compile this project and add the .dll to your Project
3. Create a class which extends `BasePlayer`
4. Implemement all the Methods (See: ExampleCode)
5. Post your code =)

### Restrictions

- You are not allowed to have a constructor for your BasePlayer and any Initialisation should be done in `Initialize()`
- You are only allowed to use the visible API in the .dll

### API

#### BasePlayer

`void Initialize()` is called before the Game stats and allows you to set up your code

`Tile CurrentTile` gives you access to the Tile you are moving

`EDirection DoMove()` here you return the direction you want to move

`ReadOnlyCollection<EDirection> ValidMoves` returns a List of Valid moves you can do

`Field Field` gives you access to the puzzle

#### Field

`bool IsPositionInBoundries(...)` returns whether the parameters are within the boundries of the Field

`Tile GetTileAtPosition(...)` returns Tile at given Position. Returns null 
when errors occur

#### Tile

`Point TargetPosition` gives you the Position this Tile has to be to win

`Point CurrentPosition` gives you the Position this Tile is currently Location

#### Point

Point represents a Location within the game, having an X and Y Coordinate. Contains operator overloads ( + and - ) eg. `var deltaPosition = tile.CurrentPosition - tile.TargetPosition`

#### EDirection

Enum which represents the direction, `Point GetOffset()` can be called to get the Offset as Point

### Example Code

```
public class RandomPlayer : BasePlayer
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var player = new RandomPlayer();
            var field = Field.PlayMatch<RandomPlayer>();
            Debug.WriteLine(field.MatchResult); 
        }

        public Random Random;

        public override EDirection DoMove()
        {
            var randomIndex = (int)(Random.NextDouble() * ValidMoves.Count()); 
            var direction = ValidMoves[randomIndex];
            return direction; 
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Random = new Random(); 
        }
    }
```

### Scoring

Players are scored by average turns needed to solve a puzzle! Good Luck!

Comment: I think this may be too easy for some PPCG users. Especially if there's no time limit, some users could probably find the optimal solution, resulting in a tie. Also, challenges should be self-contained, not relying on data from external links. So you should explain in your question description what a "sliding puzzle" is.

Answer (score 1):

## Nibbles Nostalgia

People from my generation certainly know what is the Nibbles game! If you are not here included, what I am asking is a one-line version the level 1 of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmeKHtei0qo (time: 14s—54s)

The challenge is to write a game that is a one line, one level Nibbles game using only the line buffer.

Rules:

- You must output to one or both of stderr/stdout
- Line Width is 80 chars
- Snake will always begin at the middle with 2 chars in width
- For a user to loose, the head of the Snake must hit one of the ends
- Each time a number {1...9} is catched the snake grows using the formula new_witdh= current_width + 2 * catched_number
- Of course numbers appear in an random position of the white space, never in Snake's body
- The char for each snake block body is ASCII \219 █
- It only accepts two keys, the Arrows for Left and Right. Does nothing when in the same sense; inverts head and tail when inverse
- First move is always to right
- It must be available somewhere online for me to play
- Timing between each turn of snake movement is 200 ms (This will be adjusted to make it more realistic)
- If user looses, you will output in the same line a full line of ASCII \127 char ⌂ and quit.
- If user wins, you will output in the same line a full line of ASCII \2 char ☻ and quit

It is a [code-golf] challenge, where there will be no accepted answer; I just made the challenge for my own fun!

**UPDATE:** I made a nice discovery: The original game is playable on http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=92, by mouse clicking on `Compile and Run`

Comment: How does a user win? And could you provide some ascii examples how some frames of the game should look? Does the console needs to be cleared after each line or can the new frame be printed to the next line?

Comment: "The char for each snake block body is ASCII \219 █". Not sure about this. It's adding unnecessary stuff. Why not just * or + or # or something else simple? I don't see why the character used is an important part of the challenge.

Comment: @ElPedro: To make it more like to the original game!

Comment: I hear what you are saying but the challenge is to recreate the game in the shortest code and not the graphics or am I misunderstanding what you are asking? If is a graphics challenge then that is a different story.

Comment: "The challenge is to write a game that is a one line, one level Nibbles game using only the line buffer." I guess it is possible to sometimes overcomplicate things by being too specific.

Comment: Btw, I have upvoted in the sandbox because I think this has potential. It doesn't mean that you should repost now :-)

Comment: I would also suggest that you temporarily delete from the main site as you already have one downvote (not me).

Comment: Honestly, I was confused when I saw this, because I've never heard of a "Nibbles" game. It's called "Snake". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game)

Comment: @mbomb007: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmeKHtei0qo

Comment: @Laikoni: A user wins if catches all the {1...9}  numbers without the snake hitting on the ends. The idea is to use only one line.

Comment: My point is you can't assume people know what it is. You have to include all relevant information within your post.

Comment: @mbomb007: Is it better now with the video link on the question?

Comment: 1. If all the numbers from 1 to 9 appear once, the snake would be 92 characters long and thus no longer fit into one line. 2. I don't think that a video of a 2D snake game adds much to a challenge about a custom 1D version.

Comment: @Laikoni: I made the count and the max is 74; didn't you forget that after catching 9, you don't need to make the Snake grow?

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as "ASCII 219". ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding. 2. How does the snake grow? 3. What does "*It must be available somewhere online for me to play*" mean? Only languages for which a JavaScript implementation with console emulation exists?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. OK, I accept your critic. Should I say char 219 of code page 850? 2. I stated it clearly on 5th bullet. 3 For example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm is a spot where you can play with a bunch of languages online!

Comment: No, the 5th bullet says *how much* the snake grows, not *how* the snake grows.

Comment: I don't understand what is not clear about Snake growth. Look at the video    http://youtube.com/watch?v=UmeKHtei0qo Level 1 for reference!

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Can you clarify? Now I posted a place where the original game is playable!

Comment: The QBasic Nibbles that I remember did not use 219 for a snake body segment. Each character represented 0, 1, or 2 snake body segments, since the characters were almost twice as tall as they were wide. So space was used to represent 0 body segments. QBasic extended ASCII was used with 219 representing 2 body segments (1 above the other) and 223 and 220 used to represent 1 body segment in just the top half or just the bottom half of the character respectively. See https://www.qbasic.net/en/reference/general/ascii-table.htm

Comment: @trichoplax: I knew that, I looked to the source code. But I wanted to make things simpler here because... code golf!

Answer (score 1):

## Maximize the velocity of a group of cars

---

A group of cars are in the right lane of a straight two lane highway. Each car has a preferred speed. In order to reach this preferred speed, some of the cars need to change lanes, perhaps multiple times.

All cars are exactly 1 meter long. At the start of the simulation, there is zero space between each car and the car in front of it. Acceleration is instant. Cars move at their preferred speed whenever possible. If a car would bump into another car, instead it immediately decelerates to match the speed of the car in front.

Give the starting order and preferred speed of each car, your task is to find some combination of lane changes such that all cars reach their preferred speed, and could continue to do so forever without any further lane changes, in the smallest amount of time.

### Input

Two lists are given as input:

- A list of strings that represent car names
- A list of integers that represent preferred speeds, in meters per second

The order of the car names indicates the starting order, with the first car in the list begins at the front of the pack. You can map cars to speeds using position in the list.

### Output

You will output a list of lane change events that, if followed, leads to a situation where all cars are currently driving at their preferred speeds, and could continue to do so forever. The solution must also be the fastest such solution in terms of simulation time. Another way to say this is that the timestamp of the last lane change event must be minimal.

Each event must include a timestamp and a car name. The timestamp must be the number of seconds since the beginning of the simulation, rounded to the nearest hundredth of a second.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I think this a cool question, I like how different it is from most of our other questions. However, I think having a sample implementation would be a good idea before posting it, as otherwise I'd predict many deleted answers! :P

Answer (score 1):

### Divide an array into left and right halves.

Input: An array of floating-point values, or whatever is a reasonably large numeric type in your language.

Output: Two arrays. The original array should be the concatenation of the output arrays. The sums of the elements in the two arrays should be as equal as possible.

Examples:

```
[] -> [], []
[1] -> [1], [] or [], [1]
[1, 2, 1] -> [1, 2], [1] or [1], [2, 1]
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 2], [3]
[1, -1] -> [1, -1], [] or [], [1, -1]
```

Functions or full programs please; no snippets. Normal [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules and restrictions apply.

Comment: This challenge is similar to [this recent sandbox post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11237/26981), though with a slightly different (more conventional) question format.

Comment: @VisualMelon You'll just have to take my word for it that I don't read the Sandbox myself, but I am surprised at the similarity.

Comment: No problem ;) there is an awful lot to trawl through if you don't have time to check back regularly.

Comment: [It's been done.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51468/20260)

Comment: @xnor That question doesn't have the concatenation requirement. (Not that I'm claiming that it's enough to make this question sufficiently distinctive.)

Comment: My mistake, I somehow interpreted equality as being up to ordering. Maybe it would be more obvious if you said the array is split into a left segment and a right segment. I think that definitely makes this different.

Answer (score 1):

## Decide if an integer is uniform

I was recently implementing a Local Binary Patch (LBP) descriptor, and found the need to decide if a number is uniform, as described below. You can read about why this is needed in object detection [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns).

### Input/Rules:

1. Take a (**signed!**) integer `n` in any way that seems reasonable to your language of choice.
2. The number will be given as a decimal.
3. Your approach must work with at least all 32 bit encoded integers, including `0`. This means from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, i.e. from −(2^31) to 2^31 − 1
4. Negative numbers must be turned to binary with [Two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). (With One's complement the output is the same as for the unsigned version of the number every time).
5. Only the minimal number of bits required to encode the given number matters.

### Output:

A `truthy/falsey` value if the number is uniform.

### Uniformity:

An integer `n` is considered to be uniform, if the number of transitions from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1 in the binary encoding of `n` ist less equal to 2.

### Examples:

Given the number `12`, its binary encoding is `1100`.
There is 1 transition here:

`1100
  |`

Thus, your output should be `truthy`.

Given the number `10`, its binary encoding is `1010`.
There are 3 transitions in here:

`1010
 |||`

Thus, your output should be `falsey`.

Given the number `-12`, its binary two's complement encoding is `0100`. There are 2 transition here:

`0100
 ||`

Thus, your output should be `truthy`.

Here is an example for which the **two's complement matters**:
Given the number `-125`, its binary two's complement encoding is `10000011`.
There are 2 transitions here:

`10000011
 |    |`

Thus, your output should be `truthy`.

**Side note:**
If we did the same with one's complement, the encoding of `-125` would be `10000010`, which has 3 transitions.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Sandbox notes:

This is my first code golf question, feel free to yell at me.
Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sand-box](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sand-box) [numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Comment: Seeing as it's outputting truthy/falsy, [tag:decision-problem] would be a great tag to use. Welcome to PPCG btw.

Comment: Personally, I think that input should be guaranteed to be positive rather than using two's complement encoding. That allows more bit-shifting based algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

## Make a shuffle quine!

<sub>Closely based off [this sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10997/46271), however I deleted the old one and posted this new answer for new feedback.</sub>

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[anagram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram)

An shuffle quine is defined as a quine, of which shuffled sets of "chunks" also form quines.

For example, pretend in my magical language the code `123` is a quine.

Let's split this into 3 chunks. `1`, `2`, and `3`. In your answers, these chunks can be any lengths and there can be any number greater than 1 of chunks.

You get a better score for more possible shuffled quines you can make. For example, if `21`, `23`, `13`, `312`, and `31` are also quines, in addition to `123`, you get `(15/6 = 2.5) * <sum of chunk lengths>` for your score.

Your score is calculated by the formula `sum_of_chunk_lengths * (number of possible shuffled programs/number of quines)`. In this formula, least score is better.

This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins!

Final notes:

- Each shuffled code is a quine itself, i.e. prints itself not the original program.
- Programs have to be distinct, i.e. you can't count `abb` and `abb` as 2 because you swapped the `b`s.

#### Sandbox notes:

Yeah, this is really hard. I don't think it's impossible though.

Comment: I appreciate that the scoring makes it impossible to pad the program with junk in order to get an unlimited score. However, I suspect it'll be won by one of the two-byte quines with a score of 2 × 2 ÷ 1, as it'd only be possible to beat with a score of 2 × 2 ÷ 2, 3 × 6 ÷ 5, or better.

Comment: @ais523 hm, true. I'll mess with the scoring to see what I can come up with.

Comment: It strikes me that it might be interesting to require the program to be exactly a given number of bytes long. Then the challenge would be to maximise the number of permutations that are quines. Unfortunately, a large number of bytes would be hard to score, and a small number would exclude many languages.

Comment: I don't see why it's supposed to be difficult. If each chunk is a quine (that doesn't screw up the global state somehow) then you can arrange the chunks in any order and it will still be a quine and you will score 1 for the fraction part.

Answer (score 1):

## City Zoner KoTH

You are a city zoner, and your opponent want to zone dirty industrial.  You need to stop him.  The mayor has set the following rules.

1. A random player is selected to zone the first location.  They take turns zoning area. If one player has twice as much area zoned than the other player, that player is skipped (can happen repeatedly)
2. We have a 20x20 square to zone (400 squares total). A player can choose how much they zone, but it must be a rectangle with an area of at least 5.  A player cannot zone more than 200 squares total (across the entire game)
3. If the game ends in a tie, the player who played last wins

Your goal is to ensure your opponent zones as few squares as possible.

Comment: huh, rule number 3 makes this interesting...

Answer (score 1):

## Store a secret [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a password and a secret,

- Serve at `localhost:8080`.
- If you receive a POST request to `/` with the parameter `p=(...)` then check the given password against the fed in password.

  - If it is correct, return a plaintext file with the secret.
  - If it is incorrect, return a 400 error
- Return 400 for any other requests

### Rules

- No need to salt and hash the password
- Your server should be able to start in five seconds.
- Your server must be able to server for at least five hours.
- Your server must be able to handle at least 20 connections a second at least in theory. Test script:

---

```
import requests, random, time
import sys
from string import printable

def gen_string():
    s = ''
    for i in range(random.randint(1, 20)):
        s += random.choice(printable)
    return s

def make_request(str):
    is_child = os.fork()
    if is_child:
        requests.get(str)
        sys.exit()

while True:
    for i in range(20):
        make_request(gen_string())
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: The spec seems somewhat incomplete to me. It's necessary to read between the lines even to know that the protocol the server is supposed to implement is HTTP. But even having worked that out, it's not clear how much of HTTP should be implemented. What content types must be supported for the POST body? What about encodings? When returning a 400 error, is it sufficient to set the Status header or should it also have a body?

Answer (score 1):

## Exponentiation by squaring

Given an integer *x* and a non-negative integer *n*, compute *x<sup>n</sup>* using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The key feature of this method is that the time complexity for exponentation can be reduced from *Θ*(*n*) using naive exponentiation to *Θ*(log *n*) using exponentiation by squaring. There are other names for this method as well as multiple methods which each have an equivalent time complexity. One of them will be explained but feel free to implement the one that is best suited for golfing in your language.

An iterative version is displayed below in Python

```
def exponentiate(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    y = 1
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            x = x * x
            n = n / 2
        else:
            y = x * y
            x = x * x
            n = (n - 1) / 2
    return x * y
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- Your function or program must have a time complexity of *Θ*(log *n*). Keep in mind that only time is restricted, not space.
- Your function or program must support all inputs which would not result in integer overflow in your language's integer datatype.
- You are not allowed to use any builtins that perform exponentiation.

Comment: I would change the name of your Python function as `pow` is a built-in function. Also an iterative function calls itself inside the function. The above isn't iterative. Otherwise it looks intriguing.

Comment: @JackBates Yes, a different name might be better to avoid confusion. I'm not familiar with that definition of iterative. I've usually seen recursive used to describe a function that calls itself.

Comment: @JackBates this isn't http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . And it is iterative - _recursion_ is when the function call itself, _iterative_ is when it's done in a loop instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, got a bit mixed up!

Comment: Technically the time complexity for the naïve loop isn't Θ(n) and the time complexity for the improved loop isn't Θ(lg n) because the complexity of a multiplication isn't Θ(1), *unless* you replace exponentiation with expmod. The rule about integer overflow effectively says that languages which use bounded integer types can do expmod, so on a strict reading this challenge can be answered in C but not in Python. I assume this isn't intentional. The most elegant fix is probably to require polylog time rather than log time.

Answer (score 1):

### Polytope of the pops

In 3 dimensions, there are 5 regular convex polytopes: the [platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid).
[image]

In 2 dimensions, there is an infinity of regular convex polytopes: the triangle, the square, the pentagon, the hexagon, etc…

In 4 dimensions, there are 6 such polytopes, and for 5 dimensions or more, only 3 polytopes - check that cool [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s4TqVAbfz4) for more details.

**Challenge**

Given as input an integer `n>=0`, return the number of regular convex polytopes in n-dimensional space, or -1 if the number is infinite.

The sequence ([A060296](https://oeis.org/A060296)) is (starting with 0 dimensions):

```
1, 1, -1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3...
```

**Test cases**

```
0 → 1
1 → 1
2 → -1
3 → 5
4 → 6
5 → 3
2017 → 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Interpreter chain!

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

Create an interpreter for the previous submission! The interpreter could take a string, an array of characters, etc.

Your interpreter must be able to identify each command in the input and interpret the commands.

The first answer must print the integers from 1 to 10.

**I/O**

(We need this because some languages have trouble with arrays of strings)

To chain the answers, we would need a delimiter to separate the code to interpret and the input of the interpreted code. Thus, you may use any single-character delimiter of your choice to separate the two inputs. Your program must be able to separate the two inputs. Your actual input will always be one string.

**What if the previous answer is in Mathematica?**

You only need to implement the commands used in the previous submission. That is, if your program/function is run with the previous submission as input, it should become an interpreter for the submission before that. Chaining all the answers would ultimately give integers from 1 to 10.

**The commands in the previous answer are too complicated/high-level!**

There is no need to implement all aspects of those commands. Your implementation only needs to have identical behavior to the original command when it is used in identical manner to the previous answer.

For instance, if the previous answer is in Brainf*ck, and it uses only 10 cells, you do not need to make an infinite tape; a length-10 array will suffice.

If the previous answer is in Jelly and has a `.` to put 0.5 in the stack, you do not need to implement the usage of `.` to form decimal numbers (unless it is used that way).

Note: Commands that are no-op still should be implemented as no-op (your code must recognize the commands).

**How do I test my interpreter? It takes too long to evaluate the chain!**

To prevent this issue, each answer must contain a test program for the next answer. The test program must use all commands in the interpreter, in the same manner.

**Example of an interpreter**

An [Aheui](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui) program:

```
방망희 (* This program takes an integer as input and puts it in a stack (방),
          prints it as integer (망), and then terminates (희) *)
```

Invalid interpreters in Mathematica:

```
Print[Input[];Input[]]
(* This does not interpret the previous solution; it just does the identical task, ignoring the first input (the Aheui code) *)

If[Input[]=="방망희", Print[Input[]]]
(* This doesn't define each command *)

Fold[Switch[#2, "방망", Print[Input[]], "희", Abort[]]&,, Input[]]
(* This doesn't define each command *)
```

Valid interpreter in Mathematica:

```
Fold[stack={}; Switch[#2, "방", AppendTo[stack, Input[]], "망", Print[Last@stack];
  stack = Most[stack], "희", Abort[]]&,, Input[]]
```

**Rules**

- Loopholes are not allowed
- Any four consecutive answers cannot contain the same language twice.
- The second to last submission (i.e. proven not to break the chain) by Feb 12 (0:00 UTC) will be the winner.

**Answer format**

> ## 4. [Language](https://link.to.specifications)
>
> `Your code here`
>
> This answer interprets language XYZ.
>
> [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/language#@___/___)
>
> **Explanation**
>
> `code snippet`
>
> This part interprets the `x` command.
>
> `code snippet`
>
> This part interprets the `y` command.
>
> **List of commands**
>
> `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`
>
> **Test program**
>
> `... A( ... ); B( ... ); C( D( ... ) ); ...`

Comment: Why would anyone bother to read the code on input at all, when it is already known exactly what the program needs to do?

Comment: @feersum If the submission does not even read the input, it is no longer an **interpreter**. The interpreter must somehow identify each command in the input and execute the commands in order. I guess "You will need to define each function separately." wasn't that clear... (changed "function" to "command")

Comment: It's going to be hard to define a victory condition here. It'd be fairly easy to write a ridiculously long, complex program in a high-level language which would therefore be pretty much impossible to interpret.

Comment: @ais523 I edited the question. Would that work? (The winner is the second to last answer)

Comment: Possibly. I'm still unsure that the question as a whole works, but maybe you'll find a way to define things precisely.

Comment: @JungHwanMin "This is/isn't an interpreter" is a completely subjective identification which isn't appropriate in a code golf specification.

Comment: @feersum This is an answer-chaining question. Also, I don't understand how "interpreter" is a subjective word. Could you give me an example, perhaps?

Comment: I mean, for a specification on this site (other than popularity contest). OK, if it's not subjective, please give me some code which can take as input a language A, a program X in language A, and a program Y, and output whether Y is interpreting X or not.

Comment: @feersum That problem can be easily solved by requiring some explanation from the answerers (+ a link to language specifications). They would also need to write a list of commands used in their answers for the following answers.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I think what feersum is trying to say is this. An interpreter implements some programming language, which consists of some set of valid programs and their behaviors. Suppose that the first answer **A** is written in Java. The next answer **B** should be an interpreter for which **A** is a valid program whose behavior is to print the integers from 1 to 10. But what else are valid programs for **B**, and what should their behaviors be? Not every Java program has to be valid, as per the rules. What about all Java programs that use the same "commands"? (contd.)

Comment: If **A** uses a Java function that has a very complicated implementation, but only a small subset of that is needed for **A**, can **B** choose to only implement that subset? If **A** uses a syntax that's very complex to implement generally, but can be treated as a no-op in **A**, does **B** have to implement the general case? It's hard to draw the line.

Comment: @Zgarb Those are very good points. For your first comment, I would say that for language **B**, the valid programs are programs (in language **A**) that use the same commands in answer **A** with the same purpose (perhaps, it may be a good idea to require each answer to have a test program that prints from 1 to 10; the program would only use the commands in the interpreter). For your second comment, only a subset could be implemented; the no-op still has to be implemented, however (the interpreter must still acknowledge that the command is there).

Comment: In that case the chain could be broken by a language which is good at interpreting other languages but can't count from 1 to 10. (It wouldn't surprise me if one already existed; it might be fun to construct one if it doesn't.)

Comment: @ais523 The only requirement is to print numbers from 1 to 10. Technically, something like `print("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n")` would be fine. Also, if the first answer uses a for-loop (to print 1,2,3,...,10), then all the languages after that needs to have something similar... -- Anyway, I changed the requirement to "the test program must use all commands in the interpreter" to prevent such issues.

Comment: Could I get feedback instead of unexplained downvotes? If this question is too broad/impractical, it can be improved. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You do already have a lot of feedback. A downvote accompanied by an upvote on a comment explaining the problems with the question is standard practice on the StackExchange network.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The problem was that this post got three downvotes (two of which are retracted now) while only ais523 commented. The upvote counts on comments did not change.

Comment: Honestly, I think that the biggest problem is the word "commands".  Some languages, especially golfing languages, can be divided up into commands, but many cannot.  Java is a great example:  is "public" a command?  If I use public and private modifiers do they need to be implemented according to Java specification?  If I simply need to input text, and output their result, then all I really need to do is read the text, see if it matches the Java program exactly, and interpret in my own language.

Comment: @Nathan Merrill Shebangs, public, etc. can be implemented as no-op. Personally, I would simply use the lambda expression instead.

Comment: What's the defining line between a "shebang" and a "command"?  I can make a program that only works if the method is defined as public.

Comment: @NathanMerrill If "public" is not a no-op, it would be up to the implementer to make it behave like a java "public".

Comment: Nothing in any language (except those explicitly defined as no-ops) is a no-op.  This basically comes down to implementing an entire language.

Comment: @NathanMerril the "interpeter" only needs to be able to interpret the previous submission.

Comment: @JungHwanMin right, but as I said before:  if you break it up into "commands" that have to work like the language's commands, then you have to define what a command is.  Otherwise, I simply take the previous submission, and say "does it equal this text exactly, if so, then run this program".

Comment: @NathanMerrill Would this definition suffice? "A command is the smallest unit in a program that performs an action and cannot be divided into other commands without adding or changing characters." Also, there would be an exception that periods (only for methods in java, c++ etc.) and parentheses do not have to be implemented by themselves. e.g. `System.out.println(` is one "command".

Comment: @NathanMerrill The modifiers (`public`, `private`, etc.), unless the previous submission cannot function without its implementation, can be implemented as no-op (b/c the actual code would be in the `main` method; the modifiers are there because c-style languages require them.).

Comment: Ok, example submission:  In Java, I use reflection to access System.out, and check to make sure it is public.  I do the same thing with a bunch of other classes and variables.  If it passes all of my tests, then I use all of the functions I just tested to interpret the previous submission.  The next interpreter would have to implement reflection, public/private modifiers, a gazillion different libraries, and anything else I decide to do.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you can't categorize/systemize languages.  There are too many of them, and too diverse.  Submissions should be a "black box": making rules about how the submissions work rarely works.

Comment: @NathanMerrill That example would just break the chain, wouldn't it? I'm trying to make the challenge easier by making people implement only the parts that are actually serving a purpose. Modifiers and libraries in some languages are not necessary in other languages, for example. Am I going in the wrong direction? If so, how could I achieve what I want (or is it even possible)?

Comment: @NathanMerrill one example would be all the necessary parts in a Java class: `import ...; public class ... { public static void main(String[] args) { ... } }`, which doesn't really serve a purpose except for running what's under the main method. Perhaps I could require lambda expressions for languages that have the capability?

Comment: What you are aiming for is not possible. If you have a bunch of friends that want to do such a challenge casually, then it may work. However, here we require very specific rules, and trying to pin down "essential parts of a piece of code" is impossible, unless you lean on human judgement

Answer (score 1):

This is my first attempt at posting a code golf question. :) The following task is something that I've been thinking about for a while now. To me it seems that most code golf tasks, while often quite amazing, are of little more than of academic interest to anyone. In the modern world (of the World Wide Web), however, RESTful web services are of utmost importance.

I haven't seen many tasks like this here, so I wonder if it's appropriate, or if it needs any additional specs?

---

**RESTful Web Service**

Your task in a nutshell: implement a web server that can store and return values in a key-value fashion.

*Rules*

1. Your application must act as a web server on localhost. The TCP port number must be 80 or higher.
2. The server must be usable with the command line tool named *[curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)*, which comes pre-installed in every Linux system.
3. The server is essentially a key-value storage where the keys are integers. You may choose to have your keys start from either 0 or 1, i.e. from localhost:80/0 or localhost:80/1. Your server must support storing *at least* 256 values, i.e. up to localhost:80/255, or /256 if you chose 1-based indexing.
4. "HTTP PUT" to an address must update the value, "HTTP GET" must retrieve it: for example, "**curl -XPUT -d 'foo' localhost:80/5**" must store the value "*foo*" into position 5. "**curl -XGET localhost:80/5**" must then return "*foo*". "GET" and "PUT" are the only HTTP verbs that need to be supported.
5. The server must always return the HTTP status code "200 OK", unless the user GETs an URL where nothing has been stored yet, in which case the status code must be "404 Not Found".
6. The server must be able to store values that are of at least 64 bytes long.

This is a code golf task, so the **shortest answer wins**.

Comment: I don't know enough about web services to judge your spec, but general advice is to have your spec be perfectly thorough and exact in describing the required behavior. In a competition to cut bytes, any "useful" features or properties that are not required will be cut. Imagine your spec is being read by an adversary trying their hardest to find loopholes that let them get away with doing as little as possible.

Comment: I'd indicate that GET and PUT are the only rest commands they need to support.  As far as I'm concerned, this challenge actually seems pretty well specified to me.

Comment: 1. There are a couple of existing questions which ask people to implement basic HTTP daemons. I think it's borderline whether the specific handling here makes a non-duplicate. Other people may have stronger opinions. 2. If I'm correct that PUT includes a request body, it would be good to specify the MIME type(s) which implementers need to handle. Not everyone has access to curl to do their own tests. 3. Point 5 of the spec seems wrong: a PUT to a URI other than the 256 specified ones should probably give a 403.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, thanks, that's good feedback, I've added that point!

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I suppose you are referring to these questions: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/advanced-code-golf-write-a-small-http-server and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/418-im-a-teapot I think the first one is too laborous to be fun and the second one is too simple. My question should be somewhere in the middle. Also I don't want to impose too many constraints, MIME types can be whatever, and for all I care the app may even crash if you PUT to wrong URLs.

Comment: There's also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12221/194 which I think is closer to yours, although it does also have a client-side HTML/JS component.

Comment: OK, ouch, that one has only 4 answers. I consider that a failure, the task obviously requires too much work so that not many people even bothered to attempt it.

Answer (score 1):

## Chicken

No, before you ask,this challenge is not about the language.

Chicken is a game played with two cars (or two computers) where two drivers face each-other on a street. Each car may swerve or stay fixed in its path. Here is an idealized payoff matrix

```
              Player 1
                  Swerve        Stay
Player 2 Swerve    +3/+3        +10/+1          
Stay                +1/+10      -25/-25
```

The values given for both swerving reflects the lack of ego damage, +3 is given for a win, but both staying results in a bothersome predicament with a high risk of a crash and where both have to reverse.

Now your job is to write a bot that will play this game. You will be provided with needed information as command line arguments.

A sample invocation will look like this.

```
foolanguage myBot.foo 4 w,w,w,w,w,w,t,w
```

Where the first command line argument is a string containing the number of goes you have had in the match and the second is a list containing each of you and your opponents decisions respectively (w is swerve and t is stay). Here is a break down of the list.

```
 (your first move),(opponents first move),(your second),(opponents second)
```

This will be set up in a round robin fashion. You will play some arbitrarily high (say 100) rounds against each bot and your score will be totalled. Least damaged bot (highest scoring bot) wins!

---

### Entering

You will provide a command stem and a unique bot name. 
So the sample bot can be called fooBot, and the command stem (after which arguments are appended) looks like "foolanguage myBot.foo"

Your bot will then output w (swerve) or t (stay) with 50 ms.

Your bot must be be able to make both choices. No locking in to just one choice.

Also, your bot must be deterministic (prng's may be seeded with a private seed. If you wish to do this, insert a dummy seed, and change it right before the competition) please publish the has to ensure you don't tweak it in light of other submissions.

---

The payoff matrix isn't quite realistic, but in order to make this game make sense and various strategies to work, I decided its important to tailor it this way.

Comment: 1) The payoff matrix shows that it's best to swerve every time, so the highest scoring bot will never "stay", but this goes against the rules. (2) Does the bot play against another bot or a human? (3) Does the bot have to output for just one round or multiple?

Comment: "*your bot must be deterministic*" opens the way for metagaming where bots use seeded PRNGs and the person who posts last wins because they managed to tweak their seed to give them an edge.

Comment: @Luke serving gives three while staying four. Its in the format player 1, player 2.

Comment: @Luke output one round at a time, and then each round you receive a history, no need to store a history into a file.

Comment: @Luke also readjusted weights on the matrix

Comment: @PeterTaylor allowed hiding a seed, but mandated publishing its hash to ensure it doesnt get changed.

Comment: I think this would be more interesting if you changed the payoff matrix to include a [prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner's_dilemma)

Comment: @Luke looking back on it, I should do that. Makes it more logical

Comment: @Luke I will fix it

Comment: @Luke it seems to be a dupe if the pay off matrix exactly reflects a prisoners dilemma, will need to tweak this game. Please do edit if you can mke it more interesting

Comment: IMO, this still feels too close to prisoner's dilemma.  Despite the fact that the numbers are different, pretty much all of the existing submissions on our past challenge from [the old challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/1p5-iterated-prisoners-dilemma) will work just fine, meaning that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, it's borderline. I did a bit of reading around, and there has been research on the different performance of the same approaches when applied to iterated prisoner's dilemma and iterated chicken (with a range of parameters for both). The strategies don't perform equally well, but it's probably true that the same strategies would be posted and there wouldn't be much innovation.

Comment: Watch out for another black hat program (The one that replaced others AI)

Comment: I'm going to come up with another spin on this same theme, I like this format, but I think I need a different game  entirely.

Answer (score 1):

## Blank Card + Jera + Batteries

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

## Background

In the dungeon-style game "[The Binding of Isaac](http://bindingofisaac.com/)", there is a trick involving the use of three items, called the Blank Card, Jera, and the Battery. The Blank Card is a usable item that allows for the use of single-use items repeatedly when charged, the Jera item (single-use) allows for the duplication of items on the ground, and the Battery is a ground item which charges the current usable item. Having all three at once allows the player create as many batteries as they please, allowing them to gather all the player-stat altering items in the game with minimal effort.

However, the number of batteries which appear when repeatedly duplicating the batteries depends on a few things. Say that, at any given time, you have `n` batteries on the ground. Every time that you grab the battery and use the card simultaneously, you end up with `2n - 1` batteries on the ground (where `n` is the number of batteries you had just before picking up the battery). Your new `n` is now the current number of batteries on the ground. This sequence continues with each use of the blank card (hereon referred to as an "iteration").

## General Formula

For the sake of clarification, the general formula for this sequence may be found below:

[image: general form]

Where `b` represents the number of batteries and `n` represents the number of iterations.

## Task

Given two positive integers `x` and `y`, where `x` is an initial amount of batteries (`b0`) and `y` is the number of iterations to enact (`n`), write a program or function which finds the number of batteries you end up with on the ground.

## Examples

Let `f(x, y)` be the function defined in the task and let `[]` symbolize the steps taken to reach the answer (not included in this challenge):

```
>>> f(1, 5)
1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> f(2, 4)
17
[3, 5, 9, 17]

>>> f(8, 8)
1793
[15, 29, 57, 113, 225, 449, 897, 1793]
```

Comment: There's no really much space for interesting golfing in "*Given `x` and `y` calculate `2**y * (x-1) + 1`*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Except that's not how it works... `x_{n+1} = 2 * (x_n - 1)`, where `x_0 = y`.

Comment: The question clearly says that if you have `n` batteries and you apply one iteration you get `2n - 1` batteries, not `2(n-1)` batteries. The examples also show the iteration mapping `x_{n+1} = 2 * x_n - 1`, not `x_{n+1} = 2 * (x_n - 1)`. And the question also clearly states that "*`x` is an initial amount of batteries and `y` is the number of iterations to enact*". So your comment makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yup, my comment is off. D: Sorry. I think that the question needs rewording as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Display text in Comic Sans!

I haven't seen any challenges that require outputting text in a variable-width font, and of course I had to pick the best one.

### Goal:

Display some text in the font Comic Sans.
Characters must be variable width; `i` should use less space than `W`, for example. Kerning is not required.

#### Notes:

Your score is the program size (in bytes).
You may assume that the font "Comic Sans MS" is installed on the computer, or that a font file (or image containing the characters in that font) is in the current directory.
Storing additional data in this file is not allowed; it must be a standard font or image file.

#### Input:

A string containing the text to display.
This will only contain printable ASCII characters (32 to 126).
This can be passed to a function, typed in by the user, loaded from a file, etc.

#### Output:

The text written in Comic Sans.
This can be saved as an image, or just displayed on the screen **graphically**.
However, direct text output is not allowed.
For example, this would not be a valid HTML solution:

```css
*{font-family:"Comic Sans MS"}
```

```html
<input>
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Comment: I'd like a clearer explanation on what is allowed and what is not.  
`You are not allowed to (for example) save a .html file containing <style>*{font-family:"Comic Sans MS";}</style>Example Text` is a bit vague

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Can we assume that the font "Comic Sans MS" is installed on the system? (This challenge would be extremely different if not :P)

Comment: yeah, I said that "The size of the font is not included, but it must be in a standard format", but I think I should re-word that

Comment: you maybe should provide a list of what constitutes a standard font file, as something like a nintendo ds font file might be considered standard by some, while not by others. Same thing with raw bit map, there are a bunch of different formats. I think something like an image or font file that was used at least once before the question was posted or just providing a list of allowed formats. would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

## Crossed out 44 is still regular 44

As it happens, the HTML strikethrough `<s>4</s>` [lines up](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/61405) (at least on some systems) with the crossbar of the number `4` so that the two don't differ in appearance: <s>4</s> and 4 look like the same thing. This causes crossed out bytecounts in answers to code golf questions seem a bit confusing if they consist entirely of `4`s or if they end or begin with a `4`.

For instance, **<s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes** seems a bit silly.

However, there is a way to make the strikethrough over a `4` appear more clearly. If the bytecount begins with the digit `4`, adding a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (ASCII character `255`) before the number will make the strikethrough extend beyond the crossbar of the digit `4`. Similarly if the bytecount value ends with `4`, the non-breaking space is appended to the end.

For example, <s>44</s> becomes  <s>44</s> , <s>457</s> becomes  <s>457</s> and <s>64</s> becomes <s>64</s> .

#### The Goal

The task here is to automate this fix.

Take a string like this: `<s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes` as the input, and output or return the string with added non-breaking spaces at the end of each striken through number that ends with the digit four, and to the beginning of each striken through number that begins with the digit four.

So, for example, `<s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes` becomes `<s> 48</s> <s> 44 </s> <s>34 </s> 31 bytes`. And here's the difference in effect: **<s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes** becomes  **<s>48</s>  <s>44</s>  <s>34</s>  31 bytes**.

Be sure to use non-breaking spaces, not regular spaces. Do not add them before or after numbers that are not crossed out. You can assume that all strikethroughs are closed (so there's no `<s>` that's missing its `</s>`). If there is anything else than the number inside the strikethrough block, no spaces should be added.

Your solution can be a program or a function. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (for each language) wins. [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

Comment: Can there be spaces before or after the numbers in the strikethrough tags and what should behaviour be in that case?

Comment: I think at least make an example that shows something like <s> 48<\s> still has a nbsp added in front of the 4.

Comment: @LliwTelracs I changed it so that if there are any other characters inside the strikes, the spaces should not be added.

Comment: Lol, I didn't acknowledge that there was a way to fix it. I fixed my answer's title now xP

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong. Maybe some people have combinations of browser, system fonts, and configuration which make the strikethrough invisible, but to assert as a universal truth that the strike lines up with the crossbar is to err.

Comment: A test case with a `4` as a middle digit would be good.

Answer (score 1):

## Render STL files

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

[STL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) means **St**ereo**L**ithography. It's a common file format, used in 3D printing.

The way it works is quite simple. You change every surfaces to triangles. For example, a cube would have 12 triangles, since it has 6 sides, and each sides has 2 triangles.

In this challenge, you have to read STL(A) files and render them.

---

## Explain me more about the file format..

<strike><sup>Well, technically, I linked you to the wikipedia, but I'll just explain, You can just, uh, go to the wiki if you want, you know?</sup></strike>

Alright. the file is in this format.

```
solid [optional name]
facet normal ni nj nk
    outer loop
        vertex v1x v1y v1z
        vertex v2x v2y v2z
        vertex v3x v3y v3z
    endloop
endfacet
endsolid [optional name]
```

The part you have to look is the vertexes. you can see there are 3 vertexes each with three numbers (each of them are coodrinates of each axes). Remember I told that you change every surface to triangles? These three vertexes form a triangle.

and the part between `facet normal` and `endfacet` will be given multiple times, forming multiple triangles, forming a 3D object. like the cube I told you before.

You do not have to look at the numbers right after the `facet normal`. it will not affect the shape. (at least in this challenge)

---

## Examples

I couldn't copy all of them so I decided to leave a [link](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/stla/stla.html).

Comment: "render (ASCII)" needs to be clarified. Dumping triangles to an OpenGL renderer is is easy enough. Drawing wireframe lines with a perspective camera of our own is still fine. Drawing lines out of pixels is something I'm yet to code.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, I meant Ascii STL(STLA), which is simpler than the usually used binary STL. Look at the wiki

Comment: Are we to _output_ STLA? If so, what is the input?

Comment: @JanDvorak the input is the STLA, and the job is to render the given STLA

Comment: What does it mean to render something in ASCII? Is it sufficient to raytrace a two-char palette (hit/no-hit), or is shading or drawing the edges required? If you want edges, do we need to cull backfaces and occluded edges?

Comment: @JanDvorak Uhh, no. Noone told you to render in ASCII.

Comment: It looked like you did. So, is it okay to just dump them into an OpenGL context and be done with it? Do note the default OpenGL settings use flat shading and put the camera straight at the back-front axis.

Comment: Eh, I don't even need a 3D renderer if I ignore the Z axis and draw lines from X,Y to X,Y.

Comment: Yes. Dumping to OpenGL is completely OK. But you should really beware of matlab, since matlab has A BUILTIN

Comment: This is very underspecified. I don't see any mention of projections (orthonormal or perspective), back-face culling, z-buffering, shading, lighting, ...

Comment: It seems that this is basically "receive a bunch of triples of 3D coordinates as input, and draw the resulting triangles". Is that the OP's intent? If so, I would do the usual thing of allowing flexible input structures. If the OP's intent is to text-process STL files, I don't find that too interesting.

Comment: @GregMartin Correct. That is the challenge.

Comment: I have the feeling that wireframe with orthonormal projection would fit this challenge, but I do not know how to specify.

Answer (score 1):

## Texplode

[koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth)

---

Texplode is like Hexplode, but played on a tetragonal (square) grid. *explains the rules*

### I/O

You will provide two device files / named pipes / terminals / COM ports / other. One of these will be for input, and the other will be for output.

The input provided to your program will be a series of ASCII numbers `n^2` characters long, followed by a `;` character. The file will be flushed after this is put into it. The meaning of each number is as follows:

- `0`: There are no counters here. You can place here.
- `1`: There is one counter here, but it is not yours.
- `2`: There are two counters here, but they are not yours.
- `3`: There are three counters here, but they are not yours.
- `4`: There is one counter here, and it is yours. You can place here.
- `5`: There are two counters here, and they are yours. You can place here.
- `6`: There are three counters here, and they are yours. You can place here.

These numbers should be interpreted as being laid onto a `n` by `n` grid.

The output provided by your program should be a number followed by a `;`. The number should be the position in the input stream that your program wants to place a counter. It must be a position that you can place in, otherwise Undefined Behaviour will occur.

### Controller

The Texplode engine will be here soon.

Comment: Controller [being reviewed here](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155451/86025).

Comment: If you're communicating with external programs then I'd expect validating the response to be a negligible extra cost for the controller, and it would allow you to automate the disqualification of a player, and their exclusion from the leaderboard tournament, so the rule abiding players don't have to wait longer for a leaderboard.

Comment: Sounds awesome, by the way...

Comment: Will you choose n large enough that the game cannot be solved optimally? I dont' think it takes very large an n for this...

Comment: @trichoplax With the current implementation the invalid responders just lose their turn. If they are still connected to the stream but not sending input I couldn't do anything about it anyway, apart from adding a time limit.

Comment: @trichoplax `n` will vary. It will depend on how many contestants there are and how much computer time I have.

Comment: I'd recommend some sort of time limit as this game benefits from an arbitrary amount of calculation for even relatively small n. Without a time limit there will be incentive to use more and more time per turn, particularly in the end game.

Comment: Also, it might be a very different contest depending on how long each turn lasts. After a certain point it will be a heuristic only game, but the turn length and board size will determine how many turns into the game this happens. You could choose the turn length based on what you prefer to see.

Comment: @trichoplax Does that matter much? Many good strategies exist that are simple, including Corner Hugger. I'll probably add a ~1 minute time limit, but only so the contest can finish in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: If you'd like to see simple approaches, I'd definitely recommend a time limit, otherwise they won't stand a chance of competing.

Comment: I think it will be very interesting either way.

Comment: @trichoplax I'm inclined to find a way to convert usercode time to clock cycles and standardise the number of cycles, but that seems too complicated.

Comment: Any time limit should do, as long as the contestants know what it is. I don't think it makes much difference what it's measured in

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox notes

- This is the first time I write a controller; and it's been a while since I wrote an actual program. If you feel so inclined, feedback is appreciated.

Initial draft of the controller (java) here: https://github.com/S119349/cooperative-koth

---

### [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) The Cooperation Game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [card-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-game) [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)

In this [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, instead of *competing*, players will have to **work together** to beat a game. The player who on average gets the best results over all game runs, is the winner for this challenge. The game is inspired on the mechanics of ["The Game"](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/173090/game).

#### Game mechanics

The goal of the game is to play as much cards as possible on four piles on the table. Two piles can only accept cards in strictly increasing order, the other two in strictly decreasing order. The game is over as soon as a player cannot play a card.

**Piles**

The game starts with four piles, numbered 0 through 3 inclusive. Piles `0` and `1` accept cards in **strictly increasing** order; piles `2` and `3` accept cards in **strictly decreasing order**. Initially, the piles are

```
Pile number |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
       Card |  1  |  1  | 100 | 100 |
```

There is an exception to the rule of accepting only strictly increasing/decreasing order. You are allowed to play a card **exactly 10 less or more** respectively than the current card. For example, if the piles are

```
Pile number |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
       Card |  1  |  32 |  78 | 100 |
```

you are allowed to play `22` on pile `1`, or `88` on pile `2`.

**Taking turns**

The game starts with a shuffled draw stack containing 98 cards, numbered 2 through 99 inclusively. Each player is dealt 6 cards at the start of the game. The cards are known only to the players themselves.

During a turn, a player must play **at least two cards** <sup>Exception: you only have one card, or you're out of cards, because the draw stack is empty</sup>, up to all the cards in their hand. After their turn, the player will restock from the draw stack to 6 cards (or less at the end of the game).

**Reacting**

After each card is played, other players are allowed to react: if you have the *perfect* card in your hand, you may want to warn players not to add anything to that pile! Since your cards are secret to you, this is done by assigning **priorities** to each pile. The priority is from `0` to `5` inclusive, with `0` signifying no interest at all in that particular pile, and `5` begging other players not to add anything to that pile. Other players can use these priorities as they deem fit; including completely ignoring it.

#### Interaction with the controller

You will create a player that `extends` the `abstract Player` class. You will have to implement `void turn()` (for playing a card) and `int[] react()` (for announcing your priorities). A reference implementation, `SimpleTom`, is provided, but may be removed from the competition if there are enough competitors.

In `void turn()`, you are required to either `playCard(int card, int pile)` or `endTurn()`. Note that you may only play **one** card per invocation of `turn()`, to give other players an opportunity to `react()`. Doing anything else (playing two cards, playing no cards at all) will result in losing the game, with all the cards still in the game adding towards each player's score!

In `int[] react()`, you are required to return an array of your priorities on each pile. An example would be `return new int[] {a, b, c, d}` with `a` through `d` the priorities for each pile. Here, `0 <= a <= 5`.

To see what is happening, you have access to some members

- `ArrayList<Integer> hand` contains all cards currently in your hand.
- In the `gameState` member of the default `Player` class:

  - `int [] gameState.piles` contains the four piles. It is an integer array of size 4, with each element the last played card on that pile.
  - `Map<Player, int[]> gameState.priorities`. A map containing the latest priorities issued by each `Player` in the game.
  - `Player[] gqameState.players` can be used to list all the players in the current game; as well as determine how many cards they have by calling `int nHandCards()`. Note however that you may **not** access these `players` in any other way! (force them to do a turn, force them to lose, make them expose their hand, etc).

Concerning the other players: you **may** know who is playing and assess their skill during a game (for example, figure halfway through a game that `SimpleTom` is not trustworthy, and that two of the other players are of type `SimpleTom`). You **may not** save this information between games, or hard-code strategies concerning other players.

#### Do's and don'ts

All entries are open-source. You are encouraged to write commonly used functions (e.g., something to keep track of what cards have already been played) as separate functions, so others may use them. When you use code from others, **always attribute your source**. It is **not** OK to copy someone's algorithm and just tweak a few values - your code should be significantly different from others.

You are allowed to use a different languages than Java, if you write your own wrapper class (or use someone else's wrapper class). I usually only use Try it Online!, so I don't have any compilers installed on my Ubuntu box. If you use another language that is not available on Ubuntu by default, please include a few lines on how to install your language. Your entry will be non-competing if it takes me more than two minutes to follow these instructions, so a script or copy-pasteable command line code is preferred.

Comment: The API needs a bit of clarification: I don't see any way to access my hand; the spec contradicts itself on the return type of `react()`; and `gameState.priorities` exposes information about who else is playing: can I use that information or not?

Comment: I think I understand the game. There's just one point, which I was going to mention in the previous comment but forgot: "*Doing anything else (playing two cards, playing no cards at all) will result in losing the game!*" What does that mean exactly? I presume that it's game over for everyone, not just the misbehaving player, but what does everyone score?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point! It means game over for everyone - this is cooperative gaming, and this means no player can just wing it. However, averaging the scores over all runs should sort this out, and if it becomes a problem, I could modify the code to make sure all match combinations are played instead of my current Monte Carlo approach.

Comment: The biggest reason it's important to specify it is that now that you've confirmed that players can see who the other players are, some might want to deliberately sabotage the game in the presence of their biggest rivals.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think I outlawed that by saying *You may not save this information between games, or hard-code strategies concerning other players.*. So sure, you can *try* to detect other players and sabotage them, but you would have to write some darn good AI to do that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor if all the bots lose at the same time, then sabotaging your opponents sabotages yourself equally.

Comment: @LliwTelracs, which is why it would be selective. If there might be multiple instances of the same bot in a game, I think it could work, at least as a king-making strategy. Sanchises, "*hard-code strategies concerning other players*" sounds like it could create arguments over whether heuristic X is a hard-coded strategy targetting a given player or not.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm fine with targeting strategies at other players (isn't that what all KoTH competitors do?), **as long as** it's not hard-coded to act on a specific player (class name). In other words, your entry should behave exactly the same if another player changes their player name. So, it's allowed to know that player 1 and 2 are both the same type, and deduce that player 3 sucks, but it's not allowed to check that player 1 is actually the same bot as player 4 from the last game.

Comment: I figured I did not have to enforce that in code, but given this confusion, perhaps I better enforce that using an interfacing class instead of directly?

Comment: @Sanchises in my experience: yes. Make your API airtight.  If they shouldn't be able to modify/read something, make it impossible to do so (outside of reflection).

Comment: Also, self plug:  I've got a [KoTHComm](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/KoTHComm) Java library that makes cross-language communication easy, as well as handles many tasks, such as assigning players to games, creating random variables for determinism, and even automatically downloading submissions.  If you are interested, I'd be happy to help you use it.

Comment: @Nathan thanks for your suggestion. I should like to see what your library has to offer, but note that I code as a hobby, not professionally, so I'll excuse myself for odd questions in advance

Comment: @Sanchises Java is a hobby for me as well :)  I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53832/kothcomm), if you want to come in.

Answer (score 1):

## Implement Fizz Buzz in the C Preprocessor without the use if `#if` [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

> **Note:** I understand that there is already a question for Fizz Buzz and the preferred method is to place a bounty on an existing question instead of asking a new one. However, I believe that this warrants its own question.

[The C Preprocessor Language is Turing Complete when used in a loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540654/1459669) Your task is to implement Fizz Buzz up to and including a given integer without the use if `#if`.

- You must be able to implement Fizz Buzz for inputs from 6 to 100. You can support more if you wish, but it is not required.
- `#define INPUT <input>` will be placed at the top of the file to provide input. This is not included in your bytecount.
- The output is defined as the output of `cpp` compilation with all lines beginning with `#` stripped away fed back into `cpp` for as many times as needed until the results of two steps are identical.

  - You must be able to prove this takes a finite amount of steps.
- Specify the version of the C Preprocessor Standard to use.
- No custom compiler flags.
- No using compiler extensions.
- You can delimit items with the delimiter of your choice.
- There can be extra delimiters at the start.
- Trailing newlines are allowed.
- **`#if` is not allowed!**
- It must be exactly `Fizz`, `Buzz`, and `FizzBuzz`. Case sensitive.

A submission might look like this:

```
#define MAIN(...) \ 
  // ... 
MAIN(INPUT)
```

It will be compiled as

```
#define INPUT <input>
#define MAIN(...) \ 
   // ... 
MAIN(INPUT)
```

...using the command `cpp filename`.

Steps for getting output:

1. `cp file file2`
2. `cp file2 file`
3. `cpp file > file2`
4. Remove all lines beginning with `#` in file 2.
5. If `file2` is identical to `file`, exit. The current `file2` is defined as the output.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 until exit.

### Examples

Multiple outputs for a single input indicates all are valid

```
6 -> 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz
6 -> 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 
6 -> , 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz
6 -> , 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 
15 -> 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14, Fizz Buzz,
```

Comment: I take issue with the statement that `cpp` (the preprocessor C and C++ use) is Turing-complete; that's only true if you run it in a loop, which isn't what you're doing in this question. Also, I suspect you've forgotten that `#if` supports arithmetic operators, including modulo, that make the problem trivial. Note also that as C++ and C use the same preprocessor, there's no real need to specify "the C++ preprocessor"; just run `cpp` directly. (Note also that C++ is Turing-complete at compile time using templates, even without the preprocessor involved.)

Comment: To be clearer: "Since there is no concrete definition of what constitutes the C++ macro language" is just a huge misconception: a) there *is* a concrete definition in both the C and C++ standards of "translation phases", which separate preprocessing from the rest of the code; b) there's also a concrete definition in terms of executable programs and implementations, because it's possible to simply run `cpp` directly!

Comment: @ais523 I will change the rules 1. run in a loop 2. prevent the usage of `#if` or templates. #2: will fix

Comment: I'm not convinced `cpp` can split a string into characters, or do anything with it other than comparing it to another string (and maybe not even that if there's a hyphen), so the solutions here may be less interesting than you like; the input format is simple inappropriate for the purpose, now that you've banned #if (which would let you treat the number as an integer). Incidentally, running it in a loop is unlikely to be necessary; it's needed for the language to be Turing-complete, but it's still fairly powerful even without the loop, and likely easily powerful enough to answer the question.

Comment: @ais523 I changed it to FizzBuzz to make it much more interesting.

Comment: [tag:restricted-source]?

Answer (score 1):

## Caps Lock Morse Code

Inspired by [Blink the CAPS LOCK](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110974/19547)

Input will be a string that contains only characters that can be represented in morse code.

Convert the input string to morse code and then output it using either the Caps Lock, Num Lock or Scroll Lock indicators on the keyboard

#### Thoughts on the challenge

- I think this would be good as a code golf
- How specific should I be on defining what the output looks like, is the above sufficient or should a specific time length be given for dots and dashes?

Comment: It is a little derivative of the challenge it was inspired by.  I'm not sure if it would provoke interesting solutions.

Comment: @WheatWizard I was worried that would be the case

Answer (score 1):

## Free the Prisoners

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Your task is to free a few prisoners.** Here they are, in their cells:

```
[sad] [shame] [cops]
```

---

#### Rules, explained

*They have to be specifically freed using whitespace as replacement for each replaced letter, and then place the words to the right of the string, with an additional space separating the string area.*

The first example would become:

```
[   ] [     ] [    ] sad shame cops
```

Here is a code snippet that lets you see the prison cell before and after, plus a JS function. The square brackets (`[]`) are assumed, and do not need to be typed in the box.

```js
console.log(`Original Cell:     Waiting for input...`);
  console.log(`Emptied Cell:      Waiting for input...`);
  console.log(`Empty Cell Length: Waiting for input...`);

var string = '';
var emptyCell = function(string) {
  string = string.replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
  return ' '.repeat(string.length);
};

window.onkeyup = function() {
  string = document.getElementById('cagecontent').value;
  
  console.clear();
  
  console.log(`Original Cell:     '${string}'`);
  console.log(`Emptied Cell:      '${emptyCell(string)}'`);
  console.log(`Empty Cell Length: ${emptyCell(string).length}`);
};
```

```html
<textarea id='cagecontent' placeholder='Place text, minus the brackets, here.'></textarea>
```

There is one known error for this script: the first bracket rule doesn't work. Sorry about that.

Any whitespace on the edge of an imprisoned string (ex. `test` with a space before) would stay while emptying the cells, but would be trimmed when placed outside. The aforementioned `test` with some extra whitespace on the edge would look like this:

```
[ test]
[     ] test
```

As you can see, instead of two spaces between the original string and the freeing area, there is only one.

```
[test]]
[    ]] test
```

### Rules, simplified

- Trailing spaces are allowed.
- Replace each character in a prison cell string with a single blank space.
- Place each freed thing to the right of the original string.

  - Separate the original string and the freed things with a single space.
  - Extra whitespace on the sides of a string, when placed to the right of an original string, is removed.
- Your testing string will be: `(Let us out!)>[mad] [angery] [11]]`

  - Should result in: `(Let us out!)>[   ] [      ] [  ]] mad angery 11`
- No common loopholes, of course.

### Scoring

If you look at the tags, you can see that this question is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) puzzle. The tag wiki excerpt for this tag is:

> Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code. If you want to score by characters instead of bytes, please state this explicitly in the challenge. If source code length is not the primary scoring criterion, consider using another tag instead.

That means, the question (of any language) with the least amount of bytes is the top-scoring solution!

Comment: I noticed the number of brackets can be unbalanced. I'm not sure that's a particularly handy requirement. I'd suggest either making the excess brackets behave like regular text (ie, also be freed), or guaranteeing a balanced number of brackets,

Comment: The first ending bracket ends it. An unmatched bracket is untouched. This is already a rule.

Comment: 1) Your script and the tag wiki excerpt unnecessarily bloat the challenge without adding information, so I would recommend removing them both. 2) I read the challenge twice and did not find a `The first ending bracket ends it. An unmatched bracket is untouched.` rule, only `There is one known error for this script: the first bracket rule doesn't work.` which does not state said rule. 3) You should include not just a single but multiple test cases.

Comment: Can there be arbitrary characters between the cells? What about nested cells? Are the prisoners lower case ascii characters only?

Comment: @Laikoni Anything but a `]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Is this bitstring divisible by 3?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

---

Your challenge is to write a program or function that, given a string of bits representing a positive integer, outputs or returns a truthy value if it's divisible by 3, and a falsy value otherwise.

### Rules

- **You may not convert the input to a number in any way.** You may manipulate the string or loop through each digit, so long as you don't convert it to your language's native number type.
- Input may be given as a string or an array of digits.

#### Truthy examples

```
11
110
1001
1100
1111
10010
10101
11011
111111
10010011
1010010001
10101010101
100100101010001011110101010001
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11000001001011110010001010001001010110000010100001001000100101
1111001111110010001110111011001010100100001000110100010011101011110010010111100111011100110101000011100110011111001010000111011110010111000100001010101001000001111011011111000101001111010010010010000110101100011001011111111000111001110110011011101010011000
```

#### Falsy examples

```
1
10
100
101
111
1000
1010
1011
1101
10000
11111
10101010101011
1101001000100001000001000000100000001
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11000001001011110010001010001001010110000010100001001000100110
1101011111110011110010011101010011000001101011001111001001011010100000000110001111001101100000001010010111100111000101001001000011100000110111010010100000100001100101110000011010000010110010101011110010100110101100000011101101010000010011000001001001010101
```

---

## Sandbox questions

Obviously as a Do X without Y question this is walking a very fine line. There are several string manipulation techniques (which I won't spoil here) that I'd like to see used, rather than solutions that just loop through the string and repeatedly add a digit and take modulo 3. I could be more strict and not allow any numbers in the process, but I don't know if that's a good idea... Suggestions? Is it even possible to make this a good challenge?

Comment: This is going to be very hard to specify cleanly and still leave possible in most languages. E.g. in Java I can't loop through each digit without converting it to a native number type, because `char` *is* a native number type. (Well, I might be able to use a regex to split it into one-character strings, but that would be a crazy requirement).

Comment: I think it should be possible to treat each digit as a number, just not the full string.

Answer (score 1):

## Build the Chain Quine

This is an [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) puzzle.

Each person will write a program that is *not* a true Quine but does output its source when given the source of the last program as input.  If anything else is input your program may do whatever you wish (undefined behavior) as long as it does *not* print the source code.  The first program will be a true Quine.

## Rules

- Standard [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) rules apply
- You may not write a submission in a language that has already been used
- You may not answer twice in a row

## Goal

The goal is to have as many valid links in the chain as possible.

## Sandbox

This is a little sparse because I am still in the brain-storming phase of development.  I just wanted to write this down so I wont forget it and, of course, to get feedback.  I am not even really set on a winning criterion yet.  If you have any ideas/suggestions I am really excited to hear them (thats why I put it in the sandbox).

Comment: This is semi similar to my answer chaining quine. So I wish you good luck

Comment: yeah sure thing! http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/11615/

Comment: Mistake! http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/11615#11615

Comment: As with so many quine challenges, this falls afoul of universal quine constructors (and is also likely to get longer and longer over time, due to the need for each program to be able to reconstruct the previous entry, and thus implicitly all previous entries).

Answer (score 1):

## The Mass Murderers of Josephus

Everyone knows the Josephus challenge and its setup: you arrange `n` people in a circle, and the first person kills the second, and from then on the first alive person to the right of the previous "killer" kills the next alive person to their right. For example, with four people:

```
  1
4   2    (4 people in a loop)
  3

  1
4        (1 kills 2)
  3

  1
         (3 is closest to the right of the previous killer 1,
  3       and kills 4, who is to the right)

  1      (1 is closest to the right of the previous killer 3,
          and kills 3, who is to the right)
```

The last remaining person is `1`, in this case.

Your task, however, is to find the most murderous of these people - or whoever killed the most people. In the above example, the "murderer" is `1`, who killed 2 people: `2` and `3`.

In a bigger example, of 10 people (this is a line of 10 people, right wraps around to the left):

```
PEOPLE ALIVE  | KILL TALLY
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 |
1   3 4 5 6 7 | 1: 1
1   3   5 6 7 | 1, 3: 1
1   3   5   7 | 1, 3, 5: 1
    3   5   7 | 1, 3, 5, 7: 1
    3       7 | 3: 2; 1, 5, 7: 1
            7 | 3, 7: 2; 1, 5: 1
```

There's a tie for the person with the most kills: when a scenario like this arises, the answer is average of all the people with the most kills - in this case, it is `(3 + 7) / 2 = 5`.

### Task:

You must make a program or function that takes one input, the amount of people in the circle, and output the murderer (or the average of multiple murderers).

### Rules and specs:

- The input will never be above `2^31 - 1`.
- The input is guaranteed to be a positive integer.
- Your program must work out `100` within the timeframe of TIO (60 seconds). If you're not using TIO, provide an interpreter for me to test your program on (preferably an online one).

Comment: Averaging multiple murderers seems really artificial. I recommend either outputting the list of all most-murderous people, or saying that any of them can be the single output. Once such a change is made, I'd upvote this proposal!

Comment: Borderline, but IMO this is a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64667/194 or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5891/194. If `n` in binary starts `10` there's a unique murderer, and it's just the Josephus problem; if `n` in binary starts `11` there's a tie between two people, who are the last two people to die (simple variant on the first candidate dupe); or alternatively the last one to die is the standard Josephus problem, the second-last to die differs in the most significant bit of `n` (e.g. in the example `n=7` the most significant bit is `4` and the murderers differ by `4`).

Answer (score 1):

[Unary-binary trees](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112874/66444)

Comment: Suggestions numbered for ease of reference. 1. I think the notation would be clearer with `0 1 2` instead of `t u b`. 2. Ideally a question should be self-contained. There's plenty of room in the 30k character limit to explain what the trees are rather than relying on external links. 3. I would guess that answers should take a parameter `n` and enumerate the unary-binary trees `M(n)`, but the question can also be interpreted as wanting infinite output of `M(1)`, `M(2)`, ... This should be explicit.

Comment: I'll going to make a moderately large edit reordering some stuff. If you don't like it you can revert it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks!!! Much appreciated.

Comment: You say the output format is flexible, but does it have to list the node type 0, 1, or 2 in some form? Could each node just be a list that contains 0, 1, or 2 sublists?

Comment: It's always worth leaving something in the sandbox for at least 48 hours (longer at weekends) because other people might spot other ambiguities (as xnor has just demonstrated).

Comment: @GuyCoder No, I mean like `[[[]][]]` for  `(2 (1 0) 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Chemistry 101

### Question

`Given the atomic number of an element` in the range [1-118] print out the `group and period`, of that element as given by the following Periodic Table Of Elements.

For elements in the Lanthanide and Actinide series, (ranges [58-71] and [90-103]), you should instead print `L` for the Lanthanides and `A` for the Actinides

> You may write a [program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the our [standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.
>
> You may use any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.

<sup>[[Source]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112176/15394) <sup>I couldn't have put it better!</sup></sup>

[image]

[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#/media/File:18-column_medium-long_periodic_table.png)

### Test Cases

The output here separates the group and period with a single space

```
| Input | Output |
|   1   |  1 1   |
|   33  |  15 4  |
|   45  |  8 5   |
|   71  |  L     |
|   93  |  A     |
|   117 |  17 7  |
```

### Scoring

Simple [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest number of bytes wins

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the table with a text-based one. Otherwise, you're probably good to go. You should allow more flexible output, though. Not everyone likes converting their arrays to string.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm happy to be flexible on the output, but curious as to what benefit a text based table would provide over the image? Mobile users?

Comment: Mobile users, yes. Also, low-bandwidth users and people sitting behind overly restrictive firewalls. Not an issue here, but text is easier to edit than images. Also, prevents issues if imgur ever decides to start deleting images.

Comment: Point taken. I'll wait to see if this question is well received before I type up (or find) a text based version!

Comment: You should allow non-string output as well. Remember that answerers may submit functions instead of full programs.

Comment: I would like to maintain that the result is printed rather than just returned, but otherwise, I don't specifically mention data types.

Comment: Why would you do that? It's but an inconvenience for the answerers, not a challenge. Also, there are languages where functions can't have side effects - they can only return IO actions that the caller may execute or discard.

Comment: I think it's probably because I haven't used any of those languages. I conceed!

Comment: In Haskell: the interesting part is `f x = (foo x, bar x)`. With string output it's `f x = show (foo x, bar x)`. As an IO action it's `f x = print (foo x, bar x)` but now the type is now `IO()` instead of `(Int, Int)` or `String`. A full program is `f x = (foo x, bar x); main = readIO >> print.f` - unless the compiler can't infer that `x` is a number, in which case you have to add that bit somewhere, too.

Comment: Rather than a text-based table I would say that since there are only 118 possible inputs you might as well just provide an exhaustive test suite.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that makes me think of - do we have a tag for a finite number of possible inputs?

Answer (score 1):

## Android Lock Screen Art

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

---

## Background

In the land of Android, there exists a password type that looks like this:

[image: slide lock]

It's essentially a connect-the-dots for a password. Today, we'll be making art with it.

## The Task

Your program should export as many distinct combinations of pattern lock as image files with the following specifications:

1. Images should be 500x500 pixels large.
2. Dots should be located at positions (x, y):

   - (125, 125)
   - (125, 250)
   - (125, 375)
   - (250, 125)
   - (250, 250)
   - (250, 375)
   - (375, 125)
   - (375, 250)
   - (375, 375)
3. Lines should be drawn with a circular brush head of radius 8px.
4. Background color and line color may be any color of your choosing, but must not be the same color and it must be consistent.
5. The pattern should pass through all points ONCE, with the exception of the first point, which should be the first and last point drawn from/to.

## Examples

The following output is valid (starts at top-left):

[image: valid]

The following output is valid:

[image: valid 2]

The following output is invalid:

[image: invalid]

This breaks condition 5 (repeat use of top-left, middle, and middle-left).

The following output is also invalid:

[image: invalid 2]

This passes through the top left twice *and* the start point is not the same as the end point (breaks rule 5 twice).

## Scoring

The program with the largest number of distinct outputs wins, with the shortest program being the tiebreak.

Comment: "The program with the largest number of distinct outputs wins, with the shortest program being the tiebreak." Some simple math gives that there are 362880 possible permutations (9 options for the starting point, 8 options where to go next, 7 options left for the next point...). I think that  most, if not all, answers would opt to produce all of these.  Makes me wonder how an answer would deal with outputting all these images. Also, it would probably be useful to add a link to the I/O rules: `[x](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/13486 "Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods")`

Comment: @user2428118 So... roughly 1.5 GB of images per run on my machine. Not bad.

Comment: @user2428118 Also, that math doesn't hold, considering that choosing to go from one corner to any of the others forces pathing through intermediate points, so there are slightly fewer than that many options.

Comment: What do you mean by distinct?  There are many lock patterns that are visually the same but require a different path to be made.

Comment: Also I don't believe that your first two outputs can be made.  A closed loop is not possible on the android lock screen.

Comment: In fact, reading your specification a little more thoroughly, I don't believe that the patterns you are describing are really all that similar to the Android lock screen.

Comment: @WheatWizard It's similar - I have added the "closed loop" to the spec to increase difficulty and to sate my perfectionism.

Comment: You should still specify what types of moves are legal a little more thoroughly because there are a bunch of niche moves that can be done with the android lock screen that are not clear from your post. Especially if you change some aspects of the way they work.

Answer (score 1):

## Pratt certificates

*(bumping this proposal to see if there's any interest or comments. If so, speak now; if not, I'll delete)*

Your task: write code that generates a [Pratt certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate#Pratt_certificates) for a prime number, and write code that verifies an existing Pratt certificate.

### What's a Pratt certificate?

A Pratt certificate for a prime number `p` is a proof, of a particular type, that `p` is indeed prime. Historically, it was used in situations where proving the primality of `p` required a computation that was slow due to factoring `p-1`, but verifying the certificate (once the initial computation generated it) was quite fast.

A Pratt certificate for `p` is a recursive structure consisting of three parts: the prime `p` itself; a "witness" integer `g` (which is actually a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo `p`; see the next section for its properties); and Pratt certificates for all primes dividing `p-1`. The prime `p=2` is special: a Pratt certificate for `2` is just `2` itself.

For example, here is a Pratt certificate for `p=3911`:

```
{3911, 13, {2, {5, 2, {2}}, {17, 3, {2}}, {23, 5, {2, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}}}}}
```

The witness is `13`, and the prime factors of `3911-1` are `2`, `5`, `17`, and `23`; each of those new primes itself has a Pratt certificate, which are respectively `2`, `{5, 2, {2}}`, `{17, 3, {2}}` and `{23, 5, {2, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}}`. In this last Pratt certificate, the prime factors of `23` are `2` and `11`, so a Pratt certificate for `11` must be included, and so on.

### How do we generate a Pratt certificate?

Given a prime `p`, a Pratt certificate can be generated by finding a primitive root `g` modulo `p`; factoring `p-1` into primes (keeping only one copy of each prime factor); and recursively generating Pratt certificates for every prime factor of `p-1`.

### How do we verify a Pratt certificate?

Given a prime `p`, a witness `g`, and the prime factors `q1`, `q2`, ... of `p-1`, a Pratt certificate is verified by checking:

- that `p-1` has no prime factors other than `q1`, `q2`, ...;
- that the power `g^(p-1)` is congruent to `1` modulo `p`;
- that none of the smaller powers `g^((p-1)/q1)`, `g^((p-1)/q2)`, ... are congruent to `1` modulo `p`; and
- that each of the Pratt certificates of `q1`, `q2`, ... are themselves valid.

### Scoring and technicalities

You must write two programs or functions (or one of each): one that takes a prime number as input and returns its Pratt certificate; and one that takes an input formatted like a Pratt certificate and returns a truthy or falsy value depending on whether it is an actual Pratt certificate.

- You may choose any reasonable format for the Pratt certificate: nested lists (like the examples in this question), indented multiline strings (like the [example on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate#Pratt_certificates)), or something similar that a human being could be trivially trained into parsing by eye. You may use any reasonable convention for the trivial Pratt certificate for `2`.
- However: whatever format you choose for the Pratt certificate, your certificate-generating code must output the same format that you take as input to your certificate-verifying code. Note that your certificate-verifying code must be capable of verifying any possible Pratt certificate (in your format) for `p`, not just the one your other program generates for `p`.
- If you want, you may write a single program or function that accomplishes both tasks; in that case, your code can either determine which task is being asked of it implicitly from the input, or it can allow the user to instruct it which task to perform in some reasonable way.
- Regardless of whether you use one or two programs, no calculation can be shared or saved between different runs of the code. The programs must work correctly, on any individual prime input and on any individual certificate-shaped input, if it is the first time that code is ever being run on that system.
- You don't have to handle bogus input. You may always assume that the input to your first program is an actual prime number, and that your input to the second program syntactically matches your Pratt certificate format.
- Built-ins that generate or verify Pratt certificates are *not* allowed. Other types of built-ins (for example, those that factor integers, raise integers to powers in modular arithmetic, find primitive roots) are acceptable.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shorter code (in bytes) is better. If two programs are used, the total number of bytes in both programs is the score; if one program is used, its number of bytes is the score.

### Example Pratt certificates given prime inputs

(Note that there are many possible witnesses for any given prime, but the rest of the certificate is unique up to reordering.)

```
31 -> {31, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}}}
127 -> {127, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}
229 -> {229, 6, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {19, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}
1093 -> {1093, 5, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {13, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}
65537 -> {65537, 3, {2}}
```

(All the above outputs are examples of truthy inputs for the Pratt-certificate checking code.)

### Example falsy inputs for Pratt-certificate checking

```
{31, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}}}
{31, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}
{31, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}
{127, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}}}
{85, 4, {6, 5, {5, 2, {2}}}, {14, 3, {13, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Image Quine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The challenge is to quite simply, output an image of the source code of your program exactly as it is.

Scoring is by shortest source code wins.

The image must visibly contain the source code, and no other characters or decorations.

Standard quine rules apply, so:
- No 0-byte solutions
- No reading the source code

This is just a draft, so I'll make it more detailed should it be good enough to post.

Answer (score 1):

## Efficiently find the median

### Background

Computer scientists have spent a long time looking into ways of sorting data faster. One of the known discoveries is that if you can use the actual values of the data, sorting can be faster than if you can only compare them.

Finding the median of a list is a similar operation to sorting it (you can trivially implement it via sorting the list, then taking the element in the middle). However, if you're in an environment where you can only compare list elements (as opposed to looking at the elements directly), this *is not* typically the fastest way to find the median, as sorts are hurt more badly by the comparison restriction than finding the nth item is. What's the fastest way? Well, finding that is what this challenge is about. (However, you may want to read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to get some ideas of the approaches that are typically used. I can't guarantee that the algorithm given there is the best, though, especially on a problem of the limited size given here.)

### The task

Write a program that finds the index of the median element within a list of 31 elements. However, the program may not take the list as input, and may not inspect its values directly. Rather, the program may only make comparisons to determine which of two indexes corresponds to the larger element, via calling a separate comparison function. (In other words, your program deals entirely with list *indexes*, not list *values*.)

In order to avoid solutions that brute-force their way through all possible algorithms, you must be able to run at least one worst-case input (i.e. an input that takes the maximum possible number of comparisons), using a comparison function which simply compares two array elements, in under 10 minutes on some computer you have access to. (Solutions which do not use brute force to find an algorithm are unlikely to get anywhere near this time bound.)

### Clarifications

- You may assume that all the list elements are distinct, i.e. the comparison function will always specify that one of the elements is larger, no matter how they're compared.
- You may choose the format in which the comparison function provides output, but there must only be two possible outputs (meaning "item at first index is larger" and "item at second index is larger") for any possible query; you can't return values that mean "item at second index is *much* larger" or anything like that.
- The comparison function will act consistently, i.e. if it claims that the list item at index A is larger than the list item at index B, it will always claim that; and if it also claims that the list item at index B is larger than the list item at index C, it will additionally claim that the list item at index A is larger than the list item at index C.
- You may take the comparison function as input, or assume that it's already defined with a specific name. This is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so there's no need to try to exploit the freedom you have here to save bytes; feel free to write it in the most readable way. (The comparison function itself is not part of the submission, but you should probably include one for testing purposes and an example of what it looks like.)
- You may exploit the knowledge that the input list is exactly 31 elements long, if you wish (your program doesn't have to work in other cases, although of course it can if you want it to).
- If your language doesn't have functions, you may write the comparison function via a source code insertion, so long as the rest of the code doesn't attempt to inspect its internals. (However, you may as well just pick a different language in this case; the scoring method is based entirely on the algorithm you use, and picking a different language won't change your score at all.)

### Victory condition

Your score for this challenge is equal to the maximum number of times the comparison function can be called during a run of the program. Obviously, lower is better.

In the case of a tie, the first submission achieving the optimal score will win. (In other words, you don't gain anything from copying someone else's solution but golfing the code, or the like; you'll have to find an algorithmic improvement.)

## Sandbox questions

<s>Is this scoring method [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)? I guess I'd want to call it [atomic-fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-fastest-code) (by analogy with [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)) but that doesn't exist and I'm not sure it should be created.</s> EDIT: None of the above, it's [fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations).

Comment: I would expect the first answer to get a perfect score (because why submit one which doesn't?), at which point the question is dead.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I expect a perfect score to be fairly hard to accomplish on this challenge. I'm not sure the optimal algorithm is known, and the problem's too large to bruteforce.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question which rules out brute force.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of bruteforcing an algorithm *before* writing the program, which isn't possible with currently available amounts of computational power. You're right that you could just write a program that bruteforces all possible algorithms *at runtime* and then runs the fastest (although it would clearly be impossible to test). I should probably place a limit on runtime in order to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

## Self-Generator [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Challenge: Create a program that, given no input, outputs `n` programs (in the same language, but not necessarily the same language as the original program) separated by newlines, where each of those programs will print a section of the original program. When these sections are put together, it create the original program.

Your score is the number of bytes in the original program divided by (the number of sections that your code is split into) squared.

Comment: hm, this looks pretty interesting. The problem is, it may easily be won by a short answer with only a couple output programs.

Comment: Good point. Do you have any scoring ideas?

Comment: Not at the moment, sadly. [I have a very similar one in the sandbox, it's been mostly abandoned for a while though.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/11279#11279) (not a dupe though, by any means) I've been trying to think of a scoring criterion, and I'll keep thinking for your post also.

Comment: Also, this isn't [tag:code-golf]. That tag is for pure bytecount scoring, not formulas. Doesn't matter if it's supposed to be a shortest program.

Comment: @Riker Oh, okay. Thanks. And oh, I came up with the scoring system after putting the `[code-golf]` tag first... whoops... thanks for catching that!

Comment: Perhaps square the number of sections? `20/3` is considerably less appealing than `20/(3**2)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Perhaps that would be a better option. I'll consider that.

Comment: I think in many languages just putting the standard quine on as many lines as you please would work just fine. You might want to do something to ensure that the parts of the program are unique (perhaps say that no section can be its own quine?)

Comment: Isn't it fairly easy to score zero in the limit here, with the squared sections? In most languages, simply writing *n* copies of a standard quine will give you a score of (length of the quine) / *n* (because each copy of the quine will output the quine itself, then each of those outputs will output itself (being a quine), thus all those outputs can be combined back into the original program). It might need a few tweaks for newline handling (e.g. adding a duplicate newline at the end of the program) but those are easy enough to make.

Answer (score 1):

## Block Puzzle

A popular brain teaser commonly known as a the "IQ Block Puzzle" is comprised of 8 colored shapes which can be rotated, moved and flipped on a 8x8 grid. The puzzle is known as a [geometric magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_magic_square).

[image: Block Puzzle]

## Challenge

The challenge is to **generate** and then output all 40 possible pattern combinations that the pieces can be placed in.

The output can be in any form, but must somehow represent the position of all pieces, for example:

```
Combination 1 of 40:

  11113333
  12213333
  12214444
  22555448
  22555448
  66657788
  66657788
  66777788

...
```

There will be a winner for both:

- Shortest code in bytes
- Fastest calculation of all shapes in ms

Comment: How can you beat a simple print statement?

Comment: That looks interesting but may require additional specifications. For instance, do the 40 patterns include symmetrical/rotated solutions? Including the actual shapes of the pieces as ASCII (or whatever) rather than relying on the picture alone would also help. Otherwise looks good!

Comment: I forgot: I don't think having two distinct winning criteria is a good idea.

Comment: It should be clarified that the shapes in the sample output are the actual shapes that the program should operate with. Also, this doesn't work as [tag:fastest-code]; it's highly likely to be fastest to hardcode the output (with the only interesting part of the challenge being the fastest way to output a medium-length constant string, which is actually non-obvious).

Answer (score 1):

## Calculate Wind Chill

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

The Australian Apparent Temperature (aka, wind chill) in °C `AT` is given by this algorithm from the Australian Bureau of Meterology ([wp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill#Australian_Apparent_Temperature), [source](http://www.bom.gov.au/info/thermal_stress/#atapproximation)):

[image]

```
AT = Ta + (0.33 * e) - (.7 * ws) - 4.0
```

Where:

> `Ta` = Dry bulb temperature (°C)
>
> `e` = Water vapour pressure (hPa)
>
> `ws` = Wind speed (m/s) (at an elevation of 10 meters)

The water vapour pressure in hectoPascals `e` is given by this algorithm:

[image]

```
e = (rh / 100) * 6.105 * exp( ( 17.27 * Ta ) / ( 237.7 + Ta ) )
```

Where:

> `Ta` = Dry bulb temperature (°C)
>
> `rh` = Relative humidity [%]
>
> `exp`  represents the exponential function

The domain of:

> - `Ta` is -273.15°C to 2e7°C.
> - `e` is the real numbers
> - `ws` is 0 m/s to 2e7 m/s
> - `rh` is 0% to 100%

For inputs outside these domains, your code can do anything, including give the right answer.

---

### Output

Given a dry bulb **temperature** in °C, a **wind speed** in metres / second, and a **relative humidity** in %, your code should give the Apparent Temperature in °C, accurate to 0.1°C.

Assuming your platform or language can represent reals, for correct functions `correct_func`,

[image]

or in C, `fabsl( correct_func(Ta, rH, ws) - expected ) < 0.1`.

#### Test cases

```
value for Ta, rh, ws -> output

0   ->  -4.0
2   ->  -3.3529916671770903
4   ->  -2.6916697830145546
6   ->  -2.0132006039049877
8   ->  -1.3143308806029346
10  ->  -0.5913412821173161
12  ->  0.16000376605969002
14  ->  0.9445099696431676
16  ->  1.767610915646344
18  ->  2.6354298170017625
20  ->  3.5548453789325833
22  ->  4.5335619088440815
24  ->  5.580183785538598
26  ->  6.704294397098089
28  ->  7.916539649854112
30  ->  9.2287161435045
```

You can use a builtin function for the exponential function,
`ex`, if you like.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Answer (score 1):

## Average of a tune

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

---

Often times when I'm bored, I'll find I have a catchy tune from a song stuck in my head. Then I notice the fingers on my right hand moving as if playing that tune on a piano. If I have nothing better to do, I'll spend some time calculating where on the scale I need to play so that all five fingers get optimal usage. For example, given the tune

```
C4 C4 G4 G4 A4 A4 G4 F4 F4 E4 E4 D4 D4 C4
```

I try to center the notes such that if they were weights arranged on a board, the board would balance on my middle finger. (That's probably not a tune I'd have stuck in my head, but you get the idea.) In this case, the notes can be arranged like so:

```
C4          G4
C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 A4
C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 A4
=================
```

Now we have to balance the board. If the fulcrum is placed under E4, it will be equivalent to summing the following weights:

```
-2          +2
-2 -1  0 +1 +2 +3
-2 -1  0 +1 +2 +3
```

The result is +6, indicating that the board is leaning to the right. So we try moving right so that the fulcrum is under F4, which gives us the following:

```
-3          +1
-3 -2 -1  0 +1 +2
-3 -2 -1  0 +1 +2
```

The sum is -8, indicating that the board is leaning to the left, and also leaning further than it had before; therefore, the optimal middle note is **E4**.

By this point I've usually wasted all the time I had at my disposal, plus a good bit more. So your task is to write a program or function that does this calculation for me. Since I have more important things to waste my memory on, your code should be as short as possible.

### Task

Write a program or function which takes in a list of notes and outputs the average of these notes.

- Only notes on the scale of C major (C, D, E, F, G, A, B) should be taken into account; you never need to deal with sharps or flats.
- The notes can range from C0 to B9, inclusive; you'll never get A-1 or C12.
- The input can be given as an array, or as a string separated by spaces, newlines, commas, etc.
- The input will always contain at least one note.
- Input/output can be given in whichever case is desired. If your code only accepts one case or the other, make a note of this in your answer.
- If there are two valid outputs for a given input, you may output either or both.

### Test cases

```
Input -> Output(s)
C3 -> C3
C0 -> C0
B9 -> B9
C3 C3 -> C3
C3 D3 -> C3 or D3
C3 E3 -> D3
C0 B9 -> B4 or C5
C3 C3 C3 -> C3
C3 C3 D3 -> C3
C3 C3 E3 -> D3
C4 D4 E4 F4 -> D4 or E4
E4 E4 E4 C4 E4 G4 G3 -> D4
C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 A3 B3 C4 -> F3 or G3
C3 C3 E3 F3 G3 A3 B3 C4 -> F3
A3 A3 A3 C4 A3 A3 A3 A3 G3 F3 E3 -> A3
C5 D4 C4 C5 D4 C4 A4 C5 D4 C4 C5 D4 C4 -> F4
C4 C4 G4 G4 A4 A4 G4 F4 F4 E4 E4 D4 D4 C4 -> E4
E3 E3 F3 G3 G3 F3 E3 D3 C3 C3 D3 E3 E3 D3 D3 -> E3
C4 C4 E4 E4 A3 A3 C4 C4 F3 F3 A3 A3 G3 G3 B3 B3 -> B3
C3 C3 E4 E4 A2 A2 C4 C4 F2 F2 A3 A3 G2 G2 B3 B3 -> E3
A3 A3 A3 G3 A3 A3 A3 B3 B3 C4 C4 C4 B3 C4 G4 G4 B3 B3 -> B3
G3 G3 A3 G3 C4 B3 G3 G3 A3 G3 D4 C4 G3 G3 G4 E4 C4 B3 A3 F4 F4 E4 C4 D4 E4 -> B3
B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 B9 A6 -> A9
```

<sup>(Imaginary bonus point for each song you recognize)</sup>

### Scoring

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), **the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.**

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is there a plain "average of an array of integers" challenge, and would this be a duplicate?
- Is anything unclear, or does any information need to be added?
- Suggestions for a title? I feel like there's a "tuna fish" pun waiting to be made...
- Suggestions for test cases?

Answer (score 1):

## Multiplivision

*Hopefully a nice simple challenge that's not trivial.*

Given an input list of positive integers, alternately multiply and divide them to yield a single numerical answer, according to the following rules:

- start with the first number;
- with the remaining numbers, alternate between dividing and multiplying, one at a time (that is, in a left-associative way), with the last operation being multiplication

For example, the input `{3, 4, 2, 7}` would start with `3`, then successively compute `3 * 4 = 12`, then `12 / 2 = 6`, then `6 * 7 = 42` and output `42`. (In other words, the input `{3, 4, 2, 7}` yields the output `(((3 * 4) / 2) * 7) = 42`.) The first operation had to be a multiplication, because if we'd started with a division, then the last operation would have been division as well, which isn't right.

If the answer is not an integer, then it can be output either as an exact fraction, or as a decimal equivalent, accurate to at least 6 significant figures (either truncating or rounding the end of the decimal is fine). For decimals that terminate before 6 significant figures, either the terminating decimal alone (`1.5`) or a version with trailing zeros (`1.50000`) is fine.

Other test cases (only the numerical answer needs to be output, not the intermediate parsed expression):

```
{3} -> 3
{3, 4} -> 3 * 4 = 12
{3, 4, 2} -> 3 / 4 * 2 = 3/2 or 1.5
{5, 4, 3, 2} -> 5 * 4 / 3 * 2 = 40/3 or 13.3333
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} -> 1 * 2 / 3 * 4 / 5 * 6 / 7 * 8 = 128/35 or 3.65714
{42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42} -> 42 * 42 / 42 * 42 / 42 * 42 = 1764
{42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42} -> 42 / 42 * 42 / 42 * 42 / 42 * 42 = 42
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins! Golfed answers in all languages are welcome.

Comment: `accurate to at least 6 significant figures (including decimals that terminate before the 6th significant figure)` In the 3rd test case, shouldn't it then be 1.50000 as it has to be 6s.f.?

Comment: thanks, clarified above

Comment: In most languages that happens automatically, I really don't think it's necessary

Answer (score 1):

## Island Golf #3: Random Generation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

Given the dimensions of a rectangular patch of ocean and the desired number of land tiles, randomly generate a valid island of that many tiles within that rectangle.

### Input

Your input will be three positive integers:

- `w`, the width of the grid
- `h`, the height of the grid
- `n`, the number of tiles to make the island

`w` and `h` will always be 3 or greater. `n` will always be 1 or greater. Also, `n` will be small enough to fit inside the grid allowing for a border of water tiles: specifically, `n <= (w-2)*(h-2)`.

### Output

Your code must output a `w` by `h` rectangular grid consisting of two characters, representing land and water. (In the examples below, land is `#` and water is `.`, but you may substitute any two distinct characters you wish.) There must be exactly `n` land characters, in one contiguous block, representing an island. For example, an input of `w=11, h=9, n=40` might result in the following output:

```
...........
...##......
..#####....
..#######..
.#########.
...#######.
...#####.#.
....####...
...........
```

Requirements:

- The land tiles must all be *contiguous* (i.e. there's only one island).
- Land tiles can be connected *horizontally or vertically*, but **not** diagonally.
- The water tiles must also be contiguous (i.e. there must not be any lakes).
- The outer border of the grid must *remain as water tiles*.

Some illegal outputs:

```
.....
.#.#.   Multiple islands
.....

....
.#..    Diagonal connection
..#.
....

......
.####.  Contains a lake
.#.##.
.##...
......

....
.###    Border contains a land tile
.##.
....
```

### Details

Your solution may be a [full program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/16766). Any of the [default input and output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/16766) are acceptable. Any of [these definitions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/16766) of randomness are acceptable. Every valid island for a given input should occur with nonzero probability.

You may take the input numbers in whatever format and base is convenient for your language. You may take the three numbers in any order.

Your output may be a multiline string, a list of strings, or a 2D array/nested list of characters/single-character strings. Your output may (optionally) have a single trailing newline. As mentioned above, you may use any two distinct characters in place of `#.`.

Please mention any unusual I/O methods/formats in your submission, so others will be able to test your code more easily.

### Test cases

Given as `width, height, size`. Note that the first three test cases specify islands of maximal size for the given width and height.

```
3, 3, 1
9, 3, 7
5, 5, 9
5, 5, 1
10, 10, 60
80, 22, 1100
```

#### Validation program

Here is a [validation program](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#ZVRhb9s2EP2uX/GiDJi9SoL9YRjgYKtbbMFcdGk6LAiGYV1piZKIUKRBUlC8rfvr2R0lO3arDxJPunf37t6dnq5wr0KL3KHWosnQoJHBQ0ArH2BrehrpUTvbwYdKmeQKd0bVewwZ2gwGA@NDK1ErRxD2z@B3WhHcIM2QJncYWoN7NOvFhwcK8Bt5O9kJZZRppgyUqoFwMobqxC7psCLAD8uEAK@m94OqKJkwFVqpmjagtM7JMrxMNmhx8T1@v@wSaNy@Rvrz6OFb2@sKW4m0aAui09hAxz0hLvAVI745Qt4SkzGHj1SUKa3x1AhpwopAv94ybBgTrY@w@8jqNNFwmuhIn@7C7KG0lo3QKFvhRBmk80z/4x8fiss/P@IGb46BN194jixw9x6zN90BM6cUGx8bpLzm7vBxag28@ltyAhNpI71Mz3Lc9N1WOm7/Aas0yXFajTmvZkpl@@BVJbG1rqIA1CLlpN7DllIYTjhm6tYL/Hs858ujMftrvfilm5/a@ZJeHIi9HuOSAoEGxeNIbubnKQ/Fj7JmvQRNrrUVjZ/WqHtTBmV5SmsE8cCja3tHajbUu2MfESy8FK5s6bPDTMyz849O7rQoqZ9hnO/ZljycHTAr6cBMSqv7zmBWzZN69U@CDVVXriu8J0JkTtYKWzrPanq5RfliCXJ/tvPPbFQvlud2Hu0r3Fjqc28qTzRl@cBrozyMlJWsVoeVweDEjsSxzqpKaL3PsO3DQSwqbJLqWVtywiDoE22s5WIrK735OlC0QG8TfEo@cauvnzsc15AhCbFMixTpfykWWMxZ8eJ8tu7ZLxKl4al7YsRyGkNjKauo4bWiVopR29ISPWUIk1yrrOWWHsZGxZbGHwev5TQMyhAbMkiXPPdUNuvlT@J4dnmMcu0Jv18puj@SKBxx/ZLDc4lf1MfRY3mUPl2n2ONxfhzo5/LeRhKfV3cobgOdEOVNPa3@wDfpHM1bJ70XjfQZdk6ZqBAFvVYUViU/MeodYwbl5SrBbfqKeUlPte2E9xexc@/6sJvEZel31oc8LkLOZUQ9B/oJCAMpvCJuXo6/Hx23gljIx@DEtPU@6Z6evsvwbYblIinGKyku@YrPIj7puiyKw/en3On/AQ) in Pip to test whether your output for a given input meets the spec. It expects the three parameters and an island in the format given in this question; for example:

```
5, 5, 9
.....
.###.
.###.
.###.
.....
```

If your code has a different output format, you'll need to convert it to this format before plugging it into the validation program.

---

Sandbox questions:

- This seems like a pretty obvious random-generation challenge, but I didn't find a duplicate in a quick readthrough of previous [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) challenges. Did I miss anything?
- Should I add more stringent rules on what counts as random? [Related reading](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103239/16766)
- Should I allow output to be a 2D array (or nested list) of *any* two distinct values, not just chars and single-char strings? (E.g. integers `0` and `1`, booleans `false` and `true`, etc.)

Comment: To the downvoter, if you see this: What's your reason for downvoting? If it's something I can improve about the challenge, I'd like to know so I can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

## King of the Hill: Risk(k)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [c#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [.net](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) [windows](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows)

We all know these well spend evenings where family members and friends got to temporary enemies while playing [Risk the board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)).
The rules are not so complicated, the world is divided in territories on 6 different continents.
[image]
The different players take control over those territories and afterwards play to conquer the neighbors, form alliances and betray each other until one player reaches world domination.

But wouldn't it be cool, if you just write a bot for you to play this game? here comes your chance.

This is a King of the Hill challenge to write the best bot to play Risk(k). Like in the original game (but not entirely) the world is divided into 6 continents with a total of 41 territories. Afterwards the bots will play this game with reduced rules in a round-based setting.
Your bot can be written in [c#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Although any other language is possible which is capable of producing a dll with `cdecl`-functions or to implement [.net](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) interfaces. [The controller](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/Compiled%20Test) can be found [on Github](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-).

[image]

#### A short classis-game explanation

For all of you, who aren't familiar with this game. Every player plays on his own against all other players. The game begins with the claiming of territories (by positioning a single unit there) which is done consecutively for every player until all territories are owned by a faction. Now the players get the chance of using all units they have left to enforce their territories. Now the game begins round-wise. Every player makes a Attack-Stage and Move-Stage. In the attack-stage the players can attack other territories. This is done with dices. When thrown (the attacker and defender), the dices on each side are ordered and the highest ones are compared to each other. Whoever has the higher dice destroys a unit of the opposite side. Equal dices are considered a tie and no unit dies. You can only attack with max. 3 units at the same time, even when you have more than 3 units on your attacking territory. Also a territory with one unit cannot attack to prevent territory loss. Likewise a territory with two units can only attack with one etc. . When a territory falls to zero units, the attacking territory has to send units over (at least on and max. all except one - in the controller, all units except one are send automatically). After the attack stage, one player gets the chance to move units in the Move-Stage. One can only do so, if the territories you want to move units between are connected by territories owned by you. If your are done with this, the next players turn begins. The game ends, when one player has conquered the whole world.

### The game&rules:

- All bots have to obey the rules. Cheating bots will be punished by the program or by me. Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Each bot must be in a dll file (`name.dll`) in the same directory, as the controller.
- Each program with the c++ interface must end with `name.cpp.dll`
- When the program is started each bot gets loaded into the program and is checked if everything works. The bots get instantiated only one time when the game starts.
- All bots loaded are participating in the game.
- The initialization stage begins:

  - Each bot gets asked through the interface about its name and color.
  - All bots get introduced to another with their names.
  - All bots get consecutively called to select one of the remaining free territories. This goes till no territory is free anymore.
  - All bots get to distribute the units left to all territories. [UnitCount = Ceil(82 / BotCount) ]
- The game will stop for now till the user pushes the start-button.

  - The game will be round based where each bot will get consecutively called in four stages: Strategy-Stage, Enforcement-Stage, Attack-Stage, Move-Stage
  - The **Strategy-Stage** gives your bot the opportunity to plan a strategy for this round.
  - The **Enforcement-Stage** will give your bot the opportunity to distribute all new units to your territories. Units are gained to: Count of owned territories divided by 5 and floored, continent-bonus (owning a whole continent: North America: +5, South America: +2, Europe: +5, Africa: +3, Australia: +2, Asia: +7), capital-bonus (+1 for each owning of: East US, Brazil, North Europe, South Africa, East Australia, China) and +1 if you conquered a territory last round. You're guaranteed to get at least one new unit per round if your bot is still alive.
  - In the **Attack-Stage** you can order the program do make attacks on enemy territories which can lead to loss on your or the enemy side or you conquering a new territory. The attack will be called multiple times (max.: 100 times) as long as you make an attack every call.
  - In the **Move-Stage** you can move units around owned, connected territories. You can also again plan your strategy there for the next round.
  - Each round is time constricted for every bot with 200ms. Taking longer than this will lead to a punishment (suspension) for the next round.
- The game ends when only one bot still lives or when two bots get into an infinite loop (which is surprisingly possible and not rare for the random-bots)

### The controller&interface

How the interfaces work is explained in the template files and the example-bots.

#### For c#, .NET Programmer

Your bot has to be in a class which inherits and fully implements the [IBotInterface](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/IBotInterface). The class must be compiled into a class-library (dll).
Afterwards you can just copy your dll into the game-directory and start the game.

[EmptyBot](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/EmptyBot) is an empty template which implements the minimum required and adds a lot of useful helper-methods. It can be used as a template.

[RandomBot](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/RandomBot) is a bot which implements random behavior in all functions and stages. It acts as a full working example.

#### For C++, C, cdecl-function-able-languages

Your dll must implement eight functions with an external definition and cdecl-calling convention. A [minimal implementation](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/blob/master/EmptyCPPBot/EmptyCPPBot/EmptyCPPBot.cpp) can be looked at at [EmptyCPPBot](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/EmptyCPPBot).

Your dll can afterwards be copied into the game-directory which can be started normally afterwards. Your dll must have the following name structure: `nameOfYourDll.cpp.dll` to distinguish it from the managed dll's.

[RandomCPPBot](https://github.com/JulienKluge/KOTH_Risk-k-/tree/master/RandomCPPBot) is a bot which implements random behavior in all functions and stages. It acts as a fully working example.

### Contest Rules

- Players may submit multiple bots and are free to edit them to the deadline.
- A submission must be made as an answer on this thread. The source code can come in pieces, as full project, single file or whatever. And may be provided via download, push request or simple pasted code in the answer with code-tags. If not compile-able with Visual-Studio, i request fairly simple instructions how to compile it myself.
- A submission must specify the name and color of the bot. Although not necessary, an explanation of the bot's strategy would be nice.
- Bots are not allowed to use sources outside the dll/program (no files, no webrequest or similar things).
- Bots must be compatible with the provided interface and work under windows. Custom interfaces are not explicitly forbidden as long as they don't generate a advantage or are not compatible with the main-interface/program.
- The competition will be held in the provided controller (possible altered to automate the process) with all pairings possible to find the best 4 bots.
- The last 4 bots are fighting each other in 10 games. The bot which has won the most, wins the tournament. In a tie situation, the bots will take a single match against each other (golden goal), until one wins.
- Rules are can be changed when necessary which would be introduced on top of this thread.
- The contest ends when a week long no new submissions got made or when I say, its time to end this.
- And again, just to be sure: standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: How do you organize players into games, how do you score a single game, and how do you aggregate those scores?  When are you instantiating each bot (only once for the tournament, once for each game, or once for each method call?)  I'd recommend describing the rules of risk in full for those poor souls that don't know them.

Comment: I added a relative "short" description of the classical game. Also I added the answer to all your question into the thread but i'll also anwser it here: 
1. All players in the game directory are participating. The tournament will provide automatic pairings if necessary.
2. You score a single game by letting your bot win it. 
3. You can't. But you can restart infinitely often.
4. All bots are instantiated on the start of the program. But i could change that to the start of every game (so a reload also instantiate the bots new).

Comment: 1. What if there are lots of players (10 or even 20?).  How would you automatically pair? 2. So the second to last survivor gets the same number of points as the first one to die? What happens if there's an infinite loop? 3. You have to come up with some way to combine the scores across multiple games. 4. Are you OK if submissions store data across games? How do submissions know when a new game starts?

Comment: Risk is a famously unbalanced game in which luck is very important. To balance that out you'll need to play hundreds of games per match-up. Each game involves thousands of player decisions. I would not be surprised if it ends up taking a week to run the tournament, and part-way through that week someone might submit a new bot.

Answer (score 1):

## Check for repeated repeated words

### Task

Your code should either read in a stream/file containing printable ASCII text or define a function that takes a string containing printable ASCII and output any repeated words (including their repetitions). If you read from a file then it can have a name of your choice. Output can be a single linefeed-separated string, or a list of strings (one per repeated word).

A word is defined by the regex `[0-9A-Za-z'-]+`, i.e. it's a run of letters, digits, apostrophes and/or hyphens.

A word is considered to be repeated if it occurs twice or more in succession, separated only by one or more spaces. Repetition is case sensitive: `WORD`, `Word` and `word` are all different.

### Test Cases

Individual test cases are separated by an empty line. For each test case, the first line is the input, subsequent lines are the output. Note that the last test case does not contain any repeated words.

```
Hello how how are you?
how how

Hello my my friend. Is that that your pen pen pen?
my my
that that
pen pen pen

This is not. not a case of repeated? repeated words! Neither neither is this.
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Why do you disallow functions?

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't :)

Comment: "No other ways of getting input are allowed." Which means function arguments.

Comment: @mbomb007 That text shouldn't have been there. Thanks.

Comment: If underscores aren't a valid word character for this challenge, you'll want to add a test case that has underscores. I can see a lot of regex submissions being based on `\w` otherwise.

Comment: REgex would would win

Answer (score 1):

## Factor Sort

This challenge involves sorting positive integers based on a lexicographical ordering of their prime factorizations.

### Overview

[lexicographical sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), used in dictionaries, applies lexicographical order which extends alphabetical order to words:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaron
ab
abandoned
abc
aberdeen
```

When programming this sort, however, we typically don't extend alphabetical ordering per se, but rather we extend the order of integers used for an encoding.  For example, the same sorting above through ASCII encoding is really:

```
97
97 97
97 97 97
97 97 114 111 110
97 98
97 98 97 119 100 111 110 101 100
97 98 99
97 98 101 114 100 101 101 110
```

It is this type of ordering that we're after here... lexicographical ordering by extension of *numeric comparison* as opposed to alphabetical order.

### The Challenge

In this challenge, you will be sorting positive integers by their ordered prime factorizations (ordered in the sense that the primes are listed smallest to largest).  To handle the special case number `1`, we can simply say its prime factorization is an empty list, which lexicographically sorts prior to any other number's prime factorization.  We'll call this type of sorting factor sorting.

For example, the numbers from `1` to `10`, factor sorted, are: `1 2 4 8 6 10 3 9 5 7`.  To see why, here they are again with the ordered prime factorizations:

```
 1 []
 2 [2]
 4 [2 2]
 8 [2 2 2]
 6 [2 3]
10 [2 5]
 3 [3]
 9 [3 3]
 5 [5]
 7 [7]
```

### Rules

Write a function or program that factor sorts a list of positive integers.  Input and output can be anything reasonable, so long as the input is in the specified arbitrary order and the correct output order is apparent from the output.

Keep in mind that the output should be factor sorted numbers, not their prime factorization.

If it matters, numbers in the input will always be `≤ 7928`, so:

- The only primes in the prime factorization list are the first 1000 primes
- Composites have factors no larger than `89` inclusive

This is code golf; shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
->
1 2 4 8 6 10 3 9 5 7

100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
->
800 400 600 200 900 300 100 500 700

1472 4417 1425 1452 4480 200 339 2868 3835 4760
->
4480 1472 200 4760 1452 2868 1425 339 3835 4417

2 4 6 46 62 466 622 4666 6238
->
2 4 6 46 62 466 622 4666 6238
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Comment: This is extremely trivial in golfing languages (e.g. in CJam it's `{{mf}$}`), so may attract negative attention and may not attract answers in any language in which it's an interesting challenge (if there are any).

Comment: I think asking to compare two numbers makes for a nice challenge than sorting them. Implementing sorting based some a key function has been overdone, and many languages just have a built-in for it. Also, I suspect there are strategies for comparison that do not compute the factor vector.

Comment: @xnor "I suspect there are strategies ..." I'm confused about what you're trying to convey here.  Granting your suspicion... suppose there's indeed another way to meet the specification.  Why would that matter?

Comment: @HWalters I mean that a challenge to simply compare rather than sort might allow a wider variety of solution strategies, which makes it more interesting to golf.

Comment: Is this in the OEIS?

Comment: @Mendeleev Not sure how to answer this.  Strictly no, since it's not a sequence.  If we factor sort all positive integers, then we get an infinite number of infinite "chains" of numbers, each chain of which is ordered.  The first such chain is A000079, powers of two, so if you _stretch_ you could say this is A000079.  Powers of 3 excluding 1 is another chain after this; 2 times powers of 3 excluding 2 (i.e., 6, 18, 54, ...) is another chain between the two; etc.  There's no "second chain" (chain immediately after A000079), and no immediate predecessor chain to powers of 3 excluding 1.

Answer (score 1):

### Dice Roller

Since I have played a lot of tabletop role playing games, I am looking for an easy to use dice roller. But also being lazy, I would like to have the shortest possible solution, making this code-golf.

**Input**

You will receive as input a string, composed of 2 or 4 variables.

In the case of 2 parameters, both non-negative numbers, they represent the number of dice and the value of the dice rolled.

Examples:

```
"2 6" means rolling 2 6-sided die (colloquially written 2d6).
"3 8" means rolling 3 8-sided die (3d8).
```

In the case where 4 parameters are given, the first 2 are still numbers, as in the case of 2 parameters. The third and forth parameters represent a dice modifier, and whether the modified applies to the dice individually or the sum of all rolled values, respectively. The third parameter is a (possibly) signed number (e.g.: 2, +1, -2, ...), and the forth is a character string, either 'ind' (if the modifier applies to the individual dice) or 'all' (applies to the total sum of the dice rolled).

Examples:

```
"2 6 +1 ind" means rolling 2 6-sided die, and a modifier of +1 is applied to each individual die (can be written 2d(6+1)).
"3 8 -4 all" means rolling 3 8-sided die, and a modifier of -4 is applied to the sum of the roll (can be written (3d8)-4).
```

**Dice Properties**

- Only the following dice are acceptable (second parameter): 2 3 4 6 8 10 12 20 100.
- Regardless of modifier, a dice gives at least a value of 1 when an individual modifier is applied (so for example, "1 6 -10 ind" will return a value of 1, the minimum value allowed by this stipulation). There is no max value to an individual modifier.
- When a modifier is applied to the sum of the dice rolled (4th parameter is "all"), the sum can be less that the number of dice rolled. For example, "2 6 -20 all" will give a sum range of -18 to -8, as the lowest value of 2d6 is 2 and highest value is 12, pre-modifier. There is no min or max value to a this modifier.

**Output**

The output will be the values of the individual dice rolled, and the sum of all the dice.

Valid examples:

```
"2 6" => "3 6 : 9"
"3 8" => "1 8 5 : 14"
"2 6 -1 ind" => "1 2 : 3"
"2 6 -10 ind" => "1 1 : 2"
"3 8 +1 ind" => "2 9 6 : 17"
"2 6 10 all" => "3 6 : 19"
"2 6 -10 all" => "3 6 : -1"
```

Invalid examples (incorrect results):

```
"2 6" => "3 7 : 10" (7 is not a valid result on a 6-sided die)
"3 8" => "1 8 : 9" (not enough dice rolled)
"3 8" => "1 8 5 4 : 18" (too many dice rolled)
"2 6 -1 ind" => "1 6 : 7" (6 is not a valid result on a 6-sided die with a -1 modifier applied)
"2 6 -1 ind" => "0 5 : 5" (the die has to have a minimum value of 1 with individually applied modifier)
```

Comment: [There's this.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25416/8478) As far as I can tell, the only difference is the exact input format and your fourth parameter. I can't say whether or not people will close it as a duplicate (although there's a good chance they will, because all it does is optionally multiply the bonus by the number of dice), but it might generally be unpopular if the community feels it doesn't add anything interesting over an existing challenge.

Comment: @MartinEnder The forth parameter, limits on which dice can be rolled and the negative value modifiers. As for as I can see, the question you linked to doesn't have any consideration for `XdY-Z`, which I wanted to include as it introduces the `minimum 1` constraint for the dice rolls. But that's why I put it in the sandbox first, to see what the community thinks :)

Comment: @MartinEnder Would it maybe work if I posted a link to that question, but also specified the differences between the questions?

Comment: I personally don't think that the `max(1, roll)` makes a sufficient difference. I know it's frustrating when you put a lot of effort into a challenge spec and it turns out to have already been done (the same or similarly), but if it's almost the same as an existing challenge, it's usually better to try something else. It's ultimately up to you, of course.

Comment: @MartinEnder It got stuck in my head and wouldn't leave, so I had to get it down :P I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has anything else to add, but if it doesn't go anywhere, it's fine.

Comment: @MartinEnder I wouldn't close it as a dupe. They're similar, to be sure, but a big chunk of the linked challenge is input parsing and validation, which isn't present here. I also think that the fourth parameter (`ind` vs `all`, though I would suggest to let people use two distinct values rather than string-matching) coupled with the possibility of negative modifiers all combine to make this challenge distinct.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Instead of `"ind"/"all"`, would you suggest numerical (`0/1`) or letter (`'i'/'a'`), or something else?

Comment: Any of the above. If input parsing isn't the primary goal of your challenge (and it doesn't seem to be), don't limit folks on what inputs they and their chosen language can use best.

Answer (score 1):

## QR Code Editing: Minimum Change

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)?  This is pretty non-trivial, and finding optimal solutions is probably computationally difficult.

QR codes are a way to represent URLs and other strings of text using a 2D image.  What you might not know, however, is that a significant portion of a QR code is error-correction or unused space.

In this challenge, your program will be given a square of `1`s and `0`s representing a QR code.  This QR code may not be functional, or it may be valid or point to some destination.  Your program will also receive a string, representing the data that the new QR code should be encoded with. The goal of the program is edit the original QR code to contain the new content, but also to do it with as few pixel-flips as possible.

Here's an image describing some parts of the QR format:

[image]

QR code art generator, demonstrating how much of a QR code's space can be modified without changing the content: https://www.qrpixel.com/

Spec is only partially completed, I'll probably have to find some decent resources on QR code formats and error correction.

Comment: sound like it will make an interesting challenge once the spec is fleshed out. I assume you're going to include all the qr code info that we need?

Answer (score 1):

## Find the Translation Table [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [translation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)

Given two strings, find the translation table between the two, if the translation is not possible, output false.
Probably most easily defined through examples:

## Valid Cases

`bat`,`sap`        = `["bt","sp"]`

`sense`,`12312`    = `["se","12"]`

`rabid`,`snail`    = `["rabd","snal"]`

## Falsy Cases

`banana`,`angular` = `false` (not the same length, impossible).

`animal`,`snails`  = `false` (different character patterns, not a translation).

## Rules

- Input may be as a 2 element array or as 2 separate inputs.
- Output can be as an array, on separate lines or space delimited, but must be similar to how I have it shown.
- False output may be 0, -1 or false. If your language uses something different, ask.

## Sandbox Questions

Should I allow inputs of different length to be part of the translation? This will increase the complexity of the question by 100%. I'd suggest using `-` as the marker for a removal of a character in the translation to make it work. While it makes it more complicated, if this already exists I planned to use that to avoid a duplicate. Let me know what you think. I really like the extension idea though.

Comment: Would empty string `""` be an acceptable falsy output? Or empty list `[]`?

Comment: Shouldn't the second valid test case be `["sen","123"]`?

Comment: 1. The examples suggest, but the spec does not state, that trivial translations should be excluded. Or would `["rabid","snail"]` also be an acceptable output for `rabid`,`snail`? What about `["rabidz","snailz"]`? 2. The comment "*(different character patterns, not a translation)*" seems misleading to me. E.g. given input `abc`,`ddd` I would expect that despite having different character patterns the output should be truthy: to wit `["abc","ddd"]`. 3. Does the order of the elements in the translation tables matter? I.e. would `["tb","ps"]` be acceptable output for the first example?

Answer (score 1):

## Heapify a list

## META:

As a few people just pointed out, if you *sort* the list, this also produces a correct heap. I'm now trying to come up with a more interesting application of heaps.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[data-structures](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

Given a list of integers, *heapify* this list and return it. The sumission must have a worst case time complexity in `O(n)`.

#### Details

- Your implementation can produce min- or max-heaps, whatever is more convenient.
- Sorting the list would solve the problem, but since the worst case complexity must be in `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the list, known sorting algorithms like quicksort fail to meet this requirement.

#### Definition

A *min-heap* is a [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) where the values stored in the children of a any node are greater or equal than the ones stored in the node itself. (In a max heap it is the same just with condition *less or equal*).

A heap can be easily represented using a list `L` (here using 1 based indexing) where the children of the node at `L[k]` are `L[2*k]` (the *left* child) and `L[2*k+1]` (the *right* child).

A list `L` (lets say one based indexing is used) is (min)-*heapified* if

```
 L[k] >= L[2*k] and L[k] >= L[2*k+1] for all k
```

For a max heap we just replace `>=` with `<=`.

#### Examples

Following image represents a *max heap*:

[image]

The corresponding list representation is

```
[100, 19, 36, 17, 3, 25, 1, 2, 7]
```

The following image represents a `min heap`:

[image]

The corresponding list representation is

```
[1, 2, 3, 17, 19, 36, 7, 25, 100]
```

Comment: CJam, 1 char using the "sort" builtin

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, that totally defeats this challenge of course=)

Comment: I recommend giving a specific algorithm for heap construction, and then asking for the program to return the input list in the order that that algorithm would produce. (So you aren't quite forcing the use of the algorithm, but simply sorting won't work.)

Comment: @ais523 As an alternative to explicitly rule out some results I think we could just restrict the worst case runtime to `O(n)`, that way just sorting would not be possible anymore.

Comment: In which case you would add the [tag:restricted-complexity] tag.

Answer (score 1):

## Median fractals

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal)

I define 'Median fractal' as this.

Median fractal L<sub>1</sub> is a equilateral triangle.

for median fractal L<sub>n</sub>, Draw L<sub>n-1</sub>, then for each triangle, draw all 3 medians in the triangle.

You will be given an integer `n`, draw L<sub>n</sub>.

---

## Sandbox

Any suggestions, guys?

Comment: Would benefit from 1. A definition of the median of a vertex; 2. Diagrams of L_2 and L_3; 3. A better name. It's a variant on [triangle centre fractals](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/triangle-centre-fractals/), but perhaps would be best called the vertex-median fractal.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly "draw all 3 medians in the triangle" means. I think providing images of the first few fractals would help a lot to make the construction better understandable.

Comment: Should add: graphical output questions should at the very least specify minimum sizes to avoid trivial answers which give a 1x1 pixel bitmap output - although I suspect answers will favour vector graphics formats.

Answer (score 1):

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) These would be separate questions, and each would link to the other.

## Cops: Make a bad password policy

Over the years, people have come up with some [pretty bad password policies](http://www.davidpashley.com/2014/04/16/bad-password-policies/). Your challenge is to make such a policy, and to make a program that takes advantage of the weakness of this policy to brute force passwords written in it (a "crack"). For details on what constitutes a "crack", see the robber thread [link]. It should restrict the user to as small a selection of passwords as possible. Robbers will attempt to find cracks for your policy. If your answer is uncracked after 7 days, you make mark it safe by posting your crack. The "worst" uncracked policy (that is, the one that allows the fewest passwords) wins.

A "policy" is defined as a list of well-defined restrictions ("rules") on valid passwords. Here is an example:

> - Passwords must contain only digits, letters, and the characters '*&^'.
> - Passwords must be at most 8 characters long.
> - Passwords must not contain dictionary words (if you use this one, you must use a freely and programmatically accessible dictionary and tell us where to find it).

Policies:

- must contain no more than 10 rules,
- may not involve encryption of any kind, and
- must be clear and unambiguous

For example, these would be a bad rules:

> - The MD5 hash or zipfile of the password must not contain the letter "a". (Uses encryption of a sort)
> - Passwords may not contain special characters. (It's unclear what counts as a special character)

Your answer must contain both the policy and the number of passwords it allows.

## Robbers: Crack the bad password policy

Over the years, people have come up with some [pretty bad password policies](http://www.davidpashley.com/2014/04/16/bad-password-policies/). Your challenge is to crack such a policy. These can be found in the cops thread [link]. To crack a policy, write a program to brute force passwords that adhere to that policy. Your program must run in linear time on the number of possible passwords allowed by the policy. You may do this by enumerating or iterating over all possible passwords in some way, such as by calling a function (called, for example, `guessPassword`) for each possible password. One option is to simply hardcode the possible passwords, if there are only a few. Here is an example (JavaScript):

```javascript
function* getPasswords() {
    yield* ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

Or, using the second approach:

```javascript
function bruteForce() {
    for (let pw of ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
        if (guessPassword(pw)) {
            return pw;
        }
    }
}
```

Whoever cracks the most policies wins.

---

## Sandbox

- Is the linear time approach good? My original thought was just "your program must halt in a reasonable time", but that seems too vague, and this allows a person to crack even policies with a lot of possible passwords (though those hopefully wouldn't win anyway).
- I could also just say, "pick a password in your policy and robbers will try to crack it", maybe having the cops supply a hash of the password.

Comment: I'm worried that this sort of challenge needs far too many arbitrary-seeming restrictions on the policy to make it work. The restriction against prime numbers is already fairly arbitrary, for example. Additionally, "linear time" doesn't make sense here; there's a finite number of possible passwords (according to the victory condition), meaning that any program that enumerates them runs in O(1) (thus faster than linear) by definition. Also, I think it's fairly easy to encode an NP-complete problem into the challenge in an understandable way; many are pretty intuitive.

Comment: @ais523 Okay, if I require cops to have valid cracks, a few of those restrictions go away, since we don't have to worry about people making policies that are impossible to crack. Also, I know the programs would technically all be constant time, but I'm not sure how else to specify what constitutes a "fast" crack. I could just say, "must run in a few minutes on my machine" or something.

Comment: "*I'm not sure how else to specify what constitutes a "fast" crack*" is IMO evidence that this idea is not workable.

Answer (score 1):

## [Get the Decimal! (Posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/get-the-decimal)

Comment: Rounding on the digit, or return the exact digit? (important distinction if people can generate out to `x` and then take the last digit, for example)

Comment: Please delete this now that it is posted.

Answer (score 1):

## shortest angular path

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Let's say you have a robot and you measure the orientation of a wheel (e.g. for tracking the exact distance), but the sensor just returns an angle between -180° and 180°. Then you have the problem that even if the wheel just moved three degrees from 179° to 182° the sensor will tell you that the wheel made a jump from 179° to -178°. This makes analyzing and interpreting the data a little bit cumbersome.
Given a list of subsequent measurements your goal is now "smoothing" them out, such that from each entry `A` to the next `B`, in the list (`[...,A,B,...]`) there is at *most* a 180° jump.

#### Details

- You can also assume other (single number) representations of angles, e.g. radians (`0` to `2*pi`) or gradian (`0` to `400`) or number of turns (`0` to `1`).
- If it is more convenient, you can assume that the sensor will return data in `[0°,360°]` instead of `[-180°,180°]`.
- Which way you go if the jump is exactly `180°` (or `-180°` or `540°` etc.) is up to you.

#### Examples

```
[0 10 90 80 180 -130 -90 -120 -143 170 0] (Input)
[0 10 90 80 180 230 270 240 217 170 0]    (Output)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smooth an array

A typical signal processing operation consists in smoothing a signal to reduce noise.

A very basic way to perform such smoothing, on an array of integers, is using the following formula:

[image]

where `y'_t` is the smoothed value at index `t`, `y_t` is the original value at index `t`, and where `β` is a smoothing parameter (in `[0,1]`). Note that `y' = floor(y + 0.5)` is the classic round half up operation.

For `t = 0`, there is no `y'_(t-1)`, thus we set that `y'_0 = y_0`.

Applying that operation on a sequence of integers pictured below on the left, produces the sequence of integers pictured below on the right:

[image]

#### Challenge

Given a list of integers and `β`, output that list of integers smoothed in that way.

All integers of the list will be guaranteed to be in the interval `[1, sup)` where `sup` is the maximum integer representable in the integer type you use in your language. All integers of the input must be taken, and all integers of the output must be printed, in the decimal base (unless your language does not support decimal numbers, in which case you may use the standard base your language uses).

The input list is guaranteed to have at least 2 elements. You may take that input list in any way or format that is sensible in your language.

`β` is guaranteed to be in `[0,1]`.

#### Test cases

TODO add more

```
List                               β     Output
[1,2,7,3,11,13,26,5,18,4,3,2,1]    0.5   [1,2,5,4,8,11,19,12,15,10,7,5,3]
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Output the Name of a Number

Idea from [a recent question on math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261319/what-are-the-names-of-numbers-in-the-binary-system).

---

Write a program or a function that takes an integer from range 0 to 255 (inclusive) and outputs the name of its unsigned 8-bit binary representation. Input can be in any integer format you like, but the outputted name must match the number's unsigned 8-bit representation.

The name of the number is determined by the positions of its binary digits that are 1:

```
1 − John
10 − Watson
11 − Watson John
100 − Kevin
101 − Kevin John
110 − Kevin Watson
111 − Kevin Watson John
```

Let the names for the eight bits be `Laura`, `William`, `James`, `Mary`, `Alice`, `Kevin`, `Watson`, and `John`.

So now the name of 255 (11111111 in binary) is:

```
Laura William James Mary Alice Kevin Watson John
```

Zero doesn't have a name under this system so you may output an empty string or nothing at all. Trailing whitespace is allowed for all outputs.

**Test cases:**

```
<input (as decimal)>
<8-bit binary>
<output>

10
00001010
Alice Watson

42
00101010
James Alice Watson

128
10000000
Laura

189
10111101
Laura James Mary Alice Kevin John

55
00110111
James Mary Kevin Watson John

96
01100000
William James

37
00100101
James Kevin John

0
00000000


255
11111111
Laura William James Mary Alice Kevin Watson John
```

---

This is code-golf, show the shortest answer in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

Answer (score 1):

## Optimize for the Test Cases [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)

Given a set of test cases (pairs of input and output strings) as input, output a program in a programming language of your choice that consistently and deterministically produces the correct output for each input.

### Rules

- You may choose any programming language for the output programs, so long as it is a [programming language by our definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/45941), it existed prior to the creation of this challenge, and it is capable of taking arbitrary ASCII strings as input and producing arbitrary ASCII strings as output.
- Your solution must use the same programming language for all inputs. The output programs do not need to be in the same language as the solution.
- The output program must consistently and deterministically produce the correct output for each input. That means that, no matter how many times the program is run, it will always produce the correct output (barring any uncontrollable accidents like cosmic rays twiddling bits). PRNGs are allowed so long as a constant seed is provided (making the output consistent and deterministic).
- The test cases' inputs are provided without quotes, but you may require that the input be quoted if it is necessary or convenient (as per our [usual policy on quoted input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7633/45941)). However, you must either always or never have quotes on the input - you can't have some with quotes and some without.
- It does not matter what the output program does for inputs that are not part of the specific test case the program was created for.
- You may optionally take the number of test cases as input, if that is convenient or necessary.
- Every input in a set of test cases will be mapped to a unique output. Input values will not be repeated within a set of test cases (so `[(3, 5), (3, 6)]` wouldn't be a valid test case).

### Scoring

Your score will be equal to the sum of the byte counts of all generated programs for the set of scoring cases. Lowest score wins. This is a competition within output languages, not a competition between output languages, so don't be afraid to choose a language that is more verbose than others. I reserve the right to change the scoring cases should it be necessary.

### Examples

A C++ program that outputs (poorly-golfed) Python functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const string function_skeleton_start = "lambda s:{";
const string function_skeleton_end = "}[s]";

int main() {
    int N = 0;
    string in, out;
    stringstream program;
    program << function_skeleton_start;
    cin >> N;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        getline(cin, in);
        getline(cin, out);
        program << "'" << in << "':'" << out << "',";
    }
    program << function_skeleton_end;
    cout << program.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

An example input:

```
2
foo
bar
bar
foo
```

The corresponding output:

```py
lambda s:{'foo':'bar','bar':'foo',}[s]
```

### Test Cases

(TBD)

Comment: I'd be very interested to see some of the answers this challenge would get +1

Answer (score 1):

## Ah, Polish notation is always so confusing... [ABANDONED]

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

...so I order you to show me just how it works!<sup>That is, if you accept the challenge of course.</sup> For example, I can't even determine if `xyz01` is supposed to do `x(y(z(0)),1)` or `x(y(z(0),1))`, if I don't know the arities. And, even if I know the arities, I can't understand what `20121012100` does in first glance (I have to think much to realize it's `2(0,1(2(1(0),1(2(1(0),0)))))`). So, please, make my life easier.

---

Your challenge is, given a string, to "aritify" it. Here's how you do it:

First, you get a string (expression) containing up to 3 distinct chars, representing operators/functions with specific arities 0, 1 and 2.

Then, you convert the string to function-call representation, separating arguments with `,`s and enclosing them in `()`s (e.g. `212110102010` -> `2(1(2(1(1(0)),1(0))),2(0,1(0)))`). This is the string you will return.

## Rules

- You are guaranteed that you are only given one expression (e.g. never something like `120010` -> `1(2(0,0))1(0)` which contains more than one expression as a whole). Also, the input will never be empty.
- There will not be missing trailing arguments, so something like `20` -> `2(0,the heck?)` will never occur.
- You may choose any 3 chars for the arities (e.g. `n` for 0, `m` for 1, `d` for 2), but you must specify them in your answer. You can't use any of `()[]<>{},;` or space.
- For the brackets, you may choose any one of `()`, `[]`, `<>` or `{}`.
- For the argument separator, you may choose `,`, `;` or   (space). Also, the separator may have a trailing space, or both a trailing and a leading space, if it isn't a space. You must use a separator, it makes my life easier (how am I supposed to be able to read `211012101200` as `2(1(1(0))1(2(1(0)1(2(00)))))` instead of `2(1(1(0)),1(2(1(0),1(2(0,0)))))`? It's not properly organized.)
- Chars defining arities must be outside the brackets, to the left, so something like `1200` -> `((0,02)1)` or `((0,0)2)1` is disallowed instead of `1(2(0,0))`. I want to know what operator it is *before* I start reading the arguments.
- The 0-arity operator must not have appended brackets (e.g. `210110` -> `2(1(0),1(1(0)))`, not `2(1(0()),1(1(0())))`), it's just useless cluttering that reduces simplicity, since you can always treat them as literals.
- You may not omit the operator names (e.g. `221010121100` -> `(((),()),(((()),)))` is disallowed, `2(2(1(0),1(0)),1(2(1(1(0)),0)))` is correct).
- The chars used for input must be the same as those used for output.

## Test cases

Most of these test cases are already in this post, I've just summed them up here and added some more. I used `012` as arities, `()`s as brackets and `,` as separator here.

```
Input        -> Output

20121012100  -> 2(0,1(2(1(0),1(2(1(0),0)))))
212110102010 -> 2(1(2(1(1(0)),1(0))),2(0,1(0)))
211012101200 -> 2(1(1(0)),1(2(1(0),1(2(0,0)))))
1200         -> 1(2(0,0))
210110       -> 2(1(0),1(1(0)))
221010121100 -> 2(2(1(0),1(0)),1(2(1(1(0)),0)))
10           -> 1(0)
0            -> 0
```

## Sandbox

- Please comment if there's any error in the test-cases.
- How could I make this challenge better?
- Bumps: 3

Comment: Can I adopt and post this abandoned proposal?

Comment: @programmer5000 Not entirely abandoned yet.

Answer (score 1):

## Output "Hello, World!"... Even before it runs?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sup>Please note that this challenge only applies to languages that have a build stage and a build log.</sup>

Output "Hello, World!" to the build log. The program may or may not be compiled successfully, the job is to just output "Hello, World!" somewhere in the build log.

## Example (C/C++)

```
#pragma message("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: could it be more interesting as a rosetta-stone challenge?

Answer (score 1):

## Set The Shapes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

> **Updated on 23/05/17 with new shapes & questions**

### Challenge

Let `s` be the sequence of polygonal numbers with `S` sides and `t` be the sequence of polygonal numbers with `T` sides. Take the set union of the first `n` elements of `s` and the first `n` elements of `t`.

#### Input

3 integers, `n`, `s` & `t` where:

- `n>0`, `2<(s,t)<13` and `s!=t`
- The values of `s` & `t` each represent a different polygonal number type:

```
  3 = Triangle
  4 = Square
  5 = Pentagon
  6 = Hexagon
  7 = Heptagon
  8 = Octagon
  9 = Nonagon
 10 = Decagon
 11 = Hendecagon
 12 = Dodecagon
```

#### Output

An array of the set union of the first `n` numbers of shapes `s` and `t` in ascending order.

#### Example

(assuming 0-based indexing)

- **Input:** `n=5, s=3, t=4`
- The first 5 triangular numbers are `0, 1, 3, 6, 10`
- The first 5 square numbers are `0, 1, 4, 9, 16`
- **Output:** `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 16]`

#### Rules

- Input must be 3 separate integers
- Output must be an array (or equivalent in your chosen language)
- If your chosen language isn't capable of handling either or both of the above then [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/58974) apply
- `s` & `t` are guaranteed to be different but you must be able to handle them being input in either order - smallest first or largest first
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest byte count wins

#### Test Cases

```
Input: 5, 3, 4
0-Based Output: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 16, 20]
1-Based Output: [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15, 16, 25]

Input: 10, 9, 8
0-Based Output: [0, 1, 8, 9, 21, 24, 40, 46, 65, 75, 96, 111, 133, 154, 176, 204, 225, 261]
1-Based Output: [1, 8, 9, 21, 24, 40, 46, 65, 75, 96, 111, 133, 154, 176, 204, 225, 261, 280, 325]

Input: 1, 7, 6
0-Based Output: [0]
1-Based Output: [1]

Input: 8, 3, 3
Invalid input as both shapes are the same

Input: 0, 2, 17
Invalid input as n<1, s<3 and t>12
```

#### <s>Bonus Idea 1</s>

Brownie points if you want to increase the range for `s` & `t` and include some other polygons (e.g., star, dodecagon).

#### Bonus Idea 2

Alter the challenge to only require that solutions be able to handle 5(?) different shapes with a score reduction for each additional shape, up to a maximum of 10(?).

---

### Questions

> This is my first challenge (inspired, in part, by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118980/58974)) so all feedback very much welcome.
>
> - Should I add or remove any tags?
> - Is the above sufficiently different from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99688/58974) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79012/polygonal-numbers)?
>   **(Votes: 2 for this not being a dupe, 2 for it being a dupe of the second linked challenge)**
> - Does everything read OK & make sense?
> - Should I include the formula for each shape in the question?
>   I'm leaning towards "yes" as:
>
>   1. For those that know them, figuring them out won't be a challenge
>   2. For those that don't, figuring them out wouldn't add to the challenge
>   3. As soon as one person posts a solution containing the formulas, that makes them available to everyone else anyway.
> - Should there be more (e.g., star, tridecagon+) or less possible shapes?
> - Would it improve the challenge if I allowed solutions to pick a smaller subset of 5(?) shapes to work with? How about if that subset had to be sequential (e.g., 3-7 or 5-9 but *not* 3,5-8)?
> - What test cases should I add?
> - <s>Do the bonus ideas add to or detract from the challenge?</s>
>   **Answered: Bonuses are generally bad.**
> - Is there a better name I can give this challenge?
> - Should I be asking any other questions?!

Comment: Yeah if you want to make it bigger just add the polygons and require them. But right now it looks to be a big enough handful.

Comment: The two linked challenges don't seem similar enough to make this a duplicate (to me).

Comment: 1. I don't find "*the first `n` numbers of both shapes*" very clear. In fact, I can't find a single English phrase which cleanly expresses the meaning I reverse engineered from the example. I think it takes a few sentences or a mathematical expression. 2. The example looks wrong: what happened to `15`? 3. I disagree with trichoplax: IMO this is a duplicate of the second linked question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @PeterTaylor. 1. Could you suggest some wording for the intro to make it clearer? 2. Yep, I messed that up in an edit - it's fixed now. 3. Fair enough, that's one vote for it being a dupe and one vote against - I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: Let `S` be the sequence of polygonal numbers with `s` sides and `T` be the sequence of polygonal numbers with `t` sides. Take the set union of the first n elements of `S` and the first n elements of `T`.

Comment: Many thanks, @PeterTaylor; I've edited that in.

Comment: I agree with Peter - this is too close to the second linked challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Mego. That ties the vote; guess this stays in the sandbox a little longer, so.

Answer (score 1):

## Is it a number?

---

Given an input, output truthy if it is a valid floating point number, and falsy if it is not. The format that is used in this challenge is `[-][<integer>][.][<integer>][e[-]<integer>]`, where square brackets specify optional values. At least one group in the first section ("mantissa") needs to exist.

Here are some examples of inputs:

**Valid**

```
100
-100
10.245
-12.44
.5
-.2
0.3
-0.776
3365883.0000112
5e3         # equal to 5000
-.5245e3    # equal to -524.5
155.0e-3    # equal to 0.155
-5e-1       # equal to -0.5
.           # equal to 0.0
```

**Invalid**

```
feed me numbers
-5-3
5..2
4160e
e4
543tomatoes234
123 456
-3e0.15
4q2
```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins. However, it will not be accepted.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: For reference, `-?\d*(\d+|\.\d*)(e-?\d+)?` will match it if it's a number; it will match parts though so beware of that.

Comment: How to handle empty input, and is `-0` valid?

Comment: @Phoenix Empty input is invalid. -0 is valid for this challenge.

Comment: Please add those as test cases.

Comment: Also, `-`, `e`, `.e4`, `-e4`, `-.`

Comment: This has definitely been done before [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103441/66833)

Comment: How is `.` equal to `0.0`? Will the valid inputs be as integers, strings or either?

Comment: @Shaggy This is meant to represent floating point literals. Valid inputs are strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't break the bridges!

### Introduction:

You are a worker, who is in charge of managing a set of bridges, connecting a square grid of "nodes":

```
N - N - N
|   |   |
N - N - N
|   |   |
N - N - N
```

(the grid here is 3 by 3, but they can be larger).

Each of the bridges has a set capacity from `1` to `10`, and each of the bridges has a number of cars over them, also from `1` to `10`.

- If a bridge has a higher capacity than the number of cars on that bridge, then it is considered "safe", and you can cross over it.
- If a bridge's capacity and number of cars going over it are equal, then it is considered "stable". It won't collapse, but you can't cross over it.
- If a bridge has a lower capacity than the number of cars on that bridge, then it is considered "collapsing", and you only have a limited amount of time to fix it.

When a bridge has `n` capacity and `m` cars, with `n` smaller than `m`, the time it takes to collapse is:

```
      m + n
ceil( ----- )
      m - n
```

You must take materials (and therefore reduce the bridge's capacity) from other bridges and arrive to those bridges on time to fix them! To get materials from a bridge, you must cross over it. For example, take this small arrangement:

```
A - B
```

The bridge between `A` and `B` (which we'll call `AB`) has `3` capacity, and let's say you're on `A`, and want to take `1` material. To take the material, simply cross from `A` to `B`.

Now, `AB` has `2` capacity, and you have `1` material on you. You may only cross over bridges that are "safe", though (or if you're fixing a bridge, which is explained in the next paragraph).

To fix a bridge, you must go over it, thereby depositing all materials needed to fix the bridge. For example, in the example above, if `AB` had `1` capacity and `2` cars currently on it, and you had `2` material on you, once you cross the bridge you will have `1` material, because that is all that's required to fix the bridge.

You must fully cross a broken bridge before the bridge collapses, otherwise it will break. Each crossing of a bridge takes `1` hour, and the time it takes for the bridge to collapse is shown in the formula above. For example:

```
A
|
B
|
C - D
```

In this example, if your starting node was `A`, and `CD` only had a "lifespan" of 2 hours, the bridge would collapse before you can get to it (crossing `AB` takes 1 hour, crossing `BC` takes another hour).

### Task:

Your task is to make a program that calculates, given a list of bridges, which are represented themselves as lists of two elements (first element is capacity, second element is cars on the bridge), whether or not it's possible to fix all of the bridges. The bridges work from top-to-bottom, left-to-right - so an input of

```
[[3 2] [3 2] [2 5] [5 1]]
```

means that the actual grid looks like this:

```
    3
 A --- B
 |  2  |
3|2   2|5
 |  5  |
 C --- D
    1
```

So `AB` has a capacity of `3` and `2` cars, `AC` has a capacity of `3` and `2` cars, `BD` has a capacity of `2` and `5` cars, and `CD` has a capacity of `5` and `1` car.

### Rules / Specs:

- Your program must work for, at least, `10 * 10` grids.
- Your program may accept the input as either a string with any delimiter, or a list of lists (see example I/O).
- Your program must output the same value for true for all true values, and it must output the same value for false for all false values.
- You can either submit a full program or a function.

### Example I/O:

```
[[5 5] [5 5] [1 1] [3 3]] => true
[[2 5] [2 2] [3 3] [1 2]] => false
[[3 2] [3 2] [2 5] [5 1]] => true

NOTE, you can take the input like this as well:
[[3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 5], [5, 1]] (Python arrays)
3,2,3,2,2,5,5,1                  (Comma-separated string)
3 2 3 2 2 5 5 1                  (Space-separated string)
```

Comment: "*You may only cross over bridges that are "safe", though. To fix a bridge, you must go over it*". Huh?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed.

Comment: Will the input always have a square number of elements?

Comment: @ETHproductions The nodes are square, but the input won't always have a square number of elements, because the number of paths diverges from the number of nodes (`4` for `2 * 2`, `12` for `3 * 3`, etc.). I'm all ears to better input formats, I understand this one would be hard to process.

Comment: Ah, so it'll always be a number of the form `2*n*(n-1)`, or 4 times a triangular number. Not sure if there is any better input format...

Answer (score 1):

## How many times?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

*Inspired by [Rotational symmetry of string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121530/41024).*

Given a string, return its shortest substring that, when repeated a number of times, will produce the original string, as well as the number itself.

Test cases:

```
"ABCDABCDABCDABCD" => "ABCD", 4
"AAAAAAAAAA" => "A", 10
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 1
"" => "", 0
"Don't repeat yourself. Don't repeat yourself. " => "Don't repeat yourself. ", 2
```

Rules:

- You may return the substring and the number in any format you'd like, as long as it's consistent and clear i.e. you can always separate the number correctly from the substring e.g. `abc12` isn't allowed since you can't determine whether `abc` is to be repeated `12` times or `abc1` is to be repeated `2` times. The substring must be returned verbatim, while the number can be returned in any generally allowed format per meta consensus.
- The substring must be the shortest possible.
- For the empty string, you must return `""` and `0`.

## Sandbox

- Is the challenge description golfed enough? :P
- May I improve the return/output format?

Comment: Pleas can you change the `abc2 should be repeated 1 time` to `abc1 should be repeated 2 times`? It makes more sense.

Comment: @RandomUser Typo; should be fixed.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2862/194), [supertask](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3999/194)

Comment: What range of characters are possible within the string? Can newlines occur?

Comment: Also, why not just specify that the output format is "12\nabc"? Otherwise there may be arguments on everyone's answers about whether or not they meet the requirements.

Comment: @SteveBennett And that's what the second question in the "Sandbox" section is for. Please note that I do not intend to restrict the output format like this.

Answer (score 1):

### Quine without a character

Write a program in any language that takes as input any character, and outputs a quine in the same language, that does not contain that character.

For instance (for some made up language):

```
Input: b
Output: s(fg;fg)
Run "s(fg;fg)"
Output: s(fg;fg)

Input: (
Output: s[fg;fg]
Run "s[fg;fg]"
Output: s[fg;fg]
```

Your program must handle as input every character within the range of characters that are valid in the source code of the language you're using, including new lines, punctuation, etc.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) with penalties. Your score is `L + 1000xC` where:

- L is the length of your program in bytes
- C is the number of characters it fails to meet the requirements on.

So, if you produce a 50-character program that passes every character except for `(` and `)`, your score is 2050.

Standard loopholes are forbidden, and standard methods of input/output are ok. Outputs must be a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine), whatever that is.

Comment: [Basically a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68467/62131). The two challenges aren't *quite* the same (this one is more lenient), but the solution technique will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that one. I think that one is much harder, because your program has to output the whole quine factory. In my version, it's just a quine factory that outputs quines to order.

Answer (score 1):

## Cops & Robbers, the ultimate 1-up.

This is a cops and robbers game.

### Cops

Hello, cops. you've just solved a Code Golf challenge on the stack exchange website. How wonderful. You go to post your answer, and soon after a robber comes and beats you by 1! How infuriating!

### Your task:

Produce two programs.

The first program can be in any language,  of any length, and cannot use default loopholes. it does one thing: **Prints out a number.**

The second program must use the same language as the first, must use less bytes than the first, and **CAN** use forbidden loopholes. The second program must **print out a number which is equal to 1+ the output of your first program**

post your first program and wait 7 days. If someone cracks your program within those seven days by robbing you, please edit your answer to include [cracked] in the header. If your program is not cracked, you can edit [safe] in the header.

### Robbers

Hello, robbers. You're sneaky and looking for ways to win a golf, even if it's underhanded. You see that a cop has posted a golf for a decent score, and decide to take the lead from them.

Your task is to take a cop's answer, and beat it. Your program must use less bytes than the cop's answer and print out a number equal to only 1+ the cop's answer. You're program must also be in the same language as the cop's answer. You may use underhanded tricks and loopholes to solve the challenge. Once you complete this, you may post your solution and let the cop know they've been beat.

### Example I Os

cop: 16
robber: 17
Correct: Yes!

cop: 16
robber: 16+1
Correct: Yes!

cop: 16
robber: 16.1
correct: NO! (alternative symbols for '+' are not allowed)

cop: 16
robber: 18-1
correct: Yes! (evals to 17)

cop: 16
robber: [234,32,54,17,45,23]
correct: NO! (output must be exact).

cop: 16
robber: "1+ the cop's answer" [OR] "a number equal to only 1+ the cop's answer"
correct: NO! (smartassery is not a loophole)

cop: 16.001
robber: 17
correct: NO! (16.001+1 <> 17)

**EXCLUSIONS**: you may use any underhanded trick / loophole you want, BUT your output must match the description exactly. no new line. no trailing space.

The following loopholes are *still* forbidden:

- [Interpreting the challenge too literally](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/60951)
- [Using a made-up language specifically designed for the challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/60951)
- [Posting a code snippet instead of a complete answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/60951)
- [Using a non-free language on a Cops and Robbers challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7212/60951)

Comment: Open season on loopholes is a bad idea. E.g. for languages with short builtins for HTTP GET it becomes a search for the shortest URL shortener rather than a code golf.

Comment: @PeterTaylor howso?  the robbers must use the same language as the cops, so if you don't want to have yours cracked, use a language that doesn't support GET requests (or atleast not simply).

Comment: You need to explain cops-and-robbers rules here, in case people haven't seen them before. In particular, I'm assuming that the cop posts are required to be crackable, in which case you need to mention that the cop must keep the second program secret, but reveal it when marking the post as safe.

Comment: The `Your Task` bit isn't clear, I think you mean the end result of a cracked submission will have two programs but it kinda reads like the cops have to write two programs.

Comment: "no new line. no trailing space." Why ban trailing newlines?

Comment: As a robber, can output the string `a number equal to only 1+ the cop's answer`?

Comment: @programmer5000 no, smartassery is not a loophole.

Comment: @tuskiomi [actually, it's the most voted of them all](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/58826)

Answer (score 1):

## Add a language to a quine

---

Add a language to a quine program. Your program must output itself in all languages used so far.

Second to last answer wins after no answers have been posted for two weeks.

---

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot)

Comment: this is hard mode of existing challenge?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Basically.

Comment: @Okx So that you can't win by posting an answer which is impossible to add onto.

Answer (score 1):

## Build a simple 2D game engine

Write a program that take input specifying specs of a simple 2D game regarding the following:

- **GUI**: a space where you can print text
- **Scene**: a 2D stage where player\enemy move
- **Input** Scheme: a way to check for input
- **Player**: one object
- **Enemy**: one or more objects
- **Coin**: one object
- **Engine**: manage running scenes

The program should offer the following instructions:

- **generate**: create an object & place it in the scene
- **destroy**: destroy an object or hide it from the scene
- **move**: move an object to a different location, or apply motion
- **collision**: check if two objects are colliding or interlacing
- **write**: write to GUI
- **param**: create, modify, or read an integer
- **terminate**: stop running **update**, and run **end**
- a way to do an **if-else**

A **Scene** should at least have the following functions:

- **start**: sequence of instructions, applied once when the scene is fired
- **update**: sequence of instructions, applied N-times per second
- **end**: sequence of instructions, applied once when the scene is terminated

### Example

**Input** *the game spec*

```
GUI:1,10

SCENE:5,10

START: GEN(p1,PLAYER,5,1); GEN(e1,ENEMY,4,4); GEN(c1,COIN,3,6); PARAM(r1,0)

UPDATE:  IF(COLLISION(p1,c1), DESTROY(c1);PARAM(r1,PARAM(r1)+1));
         IF(COLLISION(p1,e1), DESTROY(p1);TERMINATE);
          IF(INPUT(ARROW-UP), MOVE(p1,-1,0));
        IF(INPUT(ARROW-DOWN), MOVE(p1,+1,0));
        IF(INPUT(ARROW-LEFT), MOVE(p1,0,-1));
       IF(INPUT(ARROW-RIGHT), MOVE(p1,0,+1));
       WRITE(g1,r1)

END: IF(PARAM(r1)=1, WRITE(g1,"YOU WON"), WRITE(g1,"GAME OVER"))
```

**Output** *an interactive game*

```
[ 0        ] <----- G:GUI (1 x 10)
+----------+
|          | <--- S:Scene (5 x 10)
|          |
|      C <-|----- C:Coin
|   E <----|----- E:Enemy
|P <-------|----- P:Player
+----------+
```

- game starts with player, one enemy, one coin
- you can control the player with arrow keys
- if player come in contact with enemy, player disappear then it ends
- if player come in contact with coin, coin disappear then it's counted
- when game ends, if coin count is 1 you win, otherwise you lose

### Meta

- What **tags** to use?
- How can I simplify the requirements so that it's possible to solve it with languages of simple means?
- I haven't seen many challenges like this, to write a program which parse instructions to create an interactive program within it, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

## Distinct strict partition counts

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[integer-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions)

---

<sup>[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71941/44713)</sup>

## The Task

Write a function or program that, given a positive integer `n`, returns or prints an array (or list, set, etc.) of length `l` such that each index `i` contains the count of distinct partitions of size `i` of `n` (one-indexed) and `l` is the maximum size of partitions for `n`.

## Definition

Let `f(n)` implement the task described.

#### Consider `f(10)`

10 may be broken into the following distinct partitions:

```
10         // Size 1
9,1        // Size 2
8,2
7,3
6,4
7,2,1      // Size 3
6,3,1
5,4,1
5,3,2
4,3,2,1    // Size 4
```

There are:

- 1 distinct partitions of size 1.
- 4 distinct partitions of size 2.
- 4 distinct partitions of size 3.
- 1 distinct partitions of size 4.

Therefore, `f(10)` returns `[1, 4, 4, 1]`.

## Test Cases

TODO

Comment: [A008289](http://oeis.org/A008289).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you. I was dreading the larger test cases.

Comment: in my opinion this suggestion is quite clearly defined and simple, I like it - but it didn't attract votes nor critique .. do people find it too mathematical? I was going to propose something similar related to enumerating Standard Young Tableaux given a partition shape

Answer (score 1):

## Odd with Odds, Even with Evens

Given an input integer `n`, express it as a sum of numbers with the following properties:

- If `n` is even, the numbers used to sum should be even.
- If `n` is odd, the integers used to sum should be odd.
- Any integer used (`x`) should be `0 < x <= ceiling(n/2)`.
- All numbers used in the summation should be unique.

  - If there are no set of distinct odd/even integers that sum to `n`, return -1.
- Output may be as an array or delimited string.

## Examples

```
Input | Output       | Comments
------+--------------+-------------------------------------------
2     | -1           | 0 < ? <= 1 = [1] (No evens, not possible)
12    | [6,4,2]      | Order is arbitrary, [2,6,4] is fine.
24    | [8,4,12]     | [2,4,6,12] works too.
9     | [1,3,5]      | Odd cases are a bit trickier to think about.
      |              | ceiling(9/2) = ceiling(4.5) -> 1 < x <= 5 -> [1,3,5]       
1     | -1           | c(1/2) = c(.5) -> 1 < x < 1 -> []
13    | [1,5,7]      | c(13/2) = c(6.5) -> 1 < x <= 7 -> [1,3,5,7]
27    | [13,11,3]    | Etc...
```

The numbers you use for each answer and how you get to the numbers you used do not matter, the only thing that matters is that they adhere to the spec. The order of the numbers does not matter, and you may have different results than provided.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), first person to mail Bill the contents of Hillary Clinton's private mailserver wins.

Comment: "no unique sum of odd/even integers" --> "no set of distinct odd/even integers that sum to"

Answer (score 1):

## Show key code

Inspired by the [showkey](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/showkey.htm) command.

## Task

You have to output the key and if is a key-up or a key-down event. I exemplify:

[image]

The output I want:

```
Key X Down
Key X Up
```

for both the instants you press or release a key.

You can output it on a console or on a GUI.

It is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shorter code wins.

Comment: I don't think this is currently clear.  What keys correspond to what key codes?  You should include either a list, or some source where one can determine which keys correspond to which codes.

Comment: @WheatWizard i think, there is standard. Also, if not, there will be keyboard/language-related key code table

Answer (score 1):

## Time bomb ping pong

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

---

### Challenge - Both teams

All users are divided into two teams based on **their PPCG ID**. For example, my ID can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan), from which you can see that my ID is 34388. To check on which team you are, run the following snippet:

```js
function update_team(){var e=document.getElementById("user-id").value,t=(document.getElementById("team-result"),"");t=e.match(/^\d+$/)||0===e.length?-1!==even_top_50.indexOf(parseInt(e))?"You are in team: ALPHA":-1!==odd_top_50.indexOf(parseInt(e))?"You are in team: BETA":0==e.length?"":"You are in team: "+(parseInt(e)%2==0?"ALPHA":"BETA"):"ID must be numeric",document.getElementById("team-result").innerHTML=t}var even_top_50=[12012,20260,17602,11259,26997,194,31716,20080,58563,47066,1426,4098,30688,56656,41723,3967,1490,31516,40695,29577,43319,15599,32686,3191,4020,67,34718,41024,7311,39328,16766,7110,31625,2867,59107,52210,16120,6710,68942,10740,9365,84,1147,15,199,7162,1308,3103,26600,59487],odd_top_50=[8478,36398,21487,3808,42545,3852,53748,48934,34388,21348,4162,34531,25180,31414,24877,31957,20469,31343,7416,45941,32014,39242,42963,11006,6828,9498,9288,14215,4198,3544,30164,33208,4372,95,41805,56178,668,47120,30525,55735,51507,57100,6699,737,39022,46855,51939,32700,59376,7209];
```

```css
.main-header,.main-input,.result{font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif;text-align:center}.main-header{font-size:24px}.main-input{display:block;margin:12px auto auto}.result{margin-top:24px}
```

```html
<br><div><div class="main-header"> Enter your PPCG ID </div><input class="main-input" maxlength="6" onkeyup="update_team()" id="user-id"> <div class="result" id="team-result"> </div></div>
```

Each user has two options:

- Start a new bomb
- Perform a counterattack

These actions are discussed here:

#### Start a new bomb

To set up a new bomb, you need to do the following:

- Create a **full** program in any *free* language which has the output **X**.
- Create a custom list of characters with a maximum of **10 characters**.
- Select *one or more characters* from the character list and insert them into your program, which will be having the exact same output **X**. This ensures that there is at least one crack for your submission.
- Only reveal the **full original program** and the **character list**. Keep the modified program *secret*. Also keep track of the iteration index, which in this case is **1** (since it's the start of a new bomb).

This is an example of a new bomb submission:

---

> ### Python 2, 9 bytes (index = 1)
>
> Outputs the number **30**.
>
> ```
> print 5*6
> ```
>
> With as character set `13579/`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXomCqZfb/PwA).

---

#### Perform a counterattack

To perform a counterattack, you need to do the following:

- Create a new **full** program with at least one character inserted from the list given by the opponent, which will have the exact same output **X**.
- Create a custom list of characters with a maximum of **10 characters**.
- Select *one or more characters* from the character list and insert them into your program, which will be having the exact same output **X**. This ensures that there is at least one crack for your submission.
- Only reveal the **full original program** and the **character list**. Keep the modified program *secret*. Also keep track of the iteration index, which in this case is the increment of the previous index.

This is an example of a counterattack (using the previous submission):

---

> ### Python 2, 12 bytes (index = 2)
>
> Defuses [Python 2, 9 bytes, Adnan](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12602/34388).
>
> Inserts `1`, `/` and `3`. Outputs **30**:
>
> ```
> print 15*6/3
> ```
>
> With as character set: `+-~58`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXomBoqmWmb/z/PwA)

---

### Scoring system

Every bomb that has not been defused for **7 days** gives the team 'index' points. If the index was 4, your team gets 4 points. You are only able to collect the points *after* you have revealed your own solution. Note that if you do not reveal your solution after the 7 days, it is still vulnerable to cracks.

As for the individual winner of the team, the person with the most cracks of the winning team gets the check mark.

---

> #### Sandbox notes
>
> - Note that this is more of an experimental challenge. Unlike the conventional **1 vs 1** cops-and-robbers challenges, this is an attempt on an **n vs n**-challenge, so I have no idea whether this is a good idea or not.
> - <s>The scoring system is a bit tricky, but I think that when a bomb has 'exploded', the opponent's team gets **(index)** points. The team with the most points at the end wins. The problem here is that the byte count might make things worse, since a larger program would make cracking the submission harder.</s>
> - A problem I'm finding here is the fact that the cop can create an arbitrarily large program, which makes it almost impossible to crack. I'm not sure whether this actually is a problem, since the 'exact same output'-rule should theoretically take care of this.
> - Perhaps add a third option for the user, where the user **defuses a bomb**. This would consist of cracking the submission, but does not create a counterattack (for cases when this is impossible, or trivial (like adding comments)).
> - I'm also not entirely sure about the 'choose your own output'-idea. Would this leave too much options for abusement?
> - Is the maximum of 10 character too much / too little? Should this also be taken in account with the scoring?
>
> Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try the wording "one or more" instead of "at least one"? It took me a while to realise that was what you meant. For more meaningful feedback about diffusions/maximums I think you'd have to decide on a scoring mechanism first. Since both teams use the same bombs to advance their score I don't think the byte count think is that big of a problem?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you for your response. I have decided that the score is just simply the sum of all index numbers of the bombs that aren't diffused after three days. This encourages counterattacks more, since the score will increment after each counterattack.

Comment: Nice. A never-ending hot potato game.

Comment: @SIGSEGV Yeah, that's what it's supposed to be. I should probably set a time limit somewhere, otherwise there will be no winner at all :p.

Comment: I'm worried that this could very easily turn into "stay online more than your opposition does", if an answer is given in a language that's very easy to crack.

Comment: 1. Defuse, not diffuse. 2. Three days is not much. A carefully timed post at the start of the weekend could slip through the net. 3. Unless I missed it, there's nothing to prevent the usual CnR-killer crypto answer. Are you absolutely certain that they won't break the challenge?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for your response. I have changed the time limit to 7 days. The main problem would indeed still be cryptographic submissions. I tried to decrease the severity of this problem by making sure that the output would remain exactly the same before and after modifying the submission, but I need to experiment a bit with this to see how this would end up. Hashing would almost certainly not be possible, unless a hashing algorithm is cracked (but I'm not 100% certain about this).

Comment: As for the hashing, this worked for me: "**Please, don't "implement RSA" or anything mean to the robbers. Use obscure languages and features, not boring encryption and hashing. I can't enforce this with rules, but you can expect torrential downvotes if all you do is `sha(input) === "abcd1234"`.**"

Answer (score 1):

## Data Categorization with a Si(g)n

### Background:

Machine learning is a very powerful tool for categorizing data. It can help find a function that splits some already known data so that unknown values can be predicted. Typically, this function should be simple so that it does not "overfit" the data. As it turns out, [previous studies](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Epedrod/papers/cacm12.pdf) have found out that the simple function *f(x) = sgn(sin(ax))* can split most data into two categories with only a single coefficient to adjust! This will definitely (not) prevent overfitting, and should (not) be used for every application of machine learning.

sgn(x) is the sign function of x. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) says,

```
         / -1 if x<0,
sgn(x) = |  0 if x=0,
         \  1 if x>0.
```

[image: Data overfitting demonstration]

### Input:

Two ordered sets/arrays/lists of integers {*m<sub>1</sub>*, *m<sub>2</sub>*, *m<sub>3</sub>*, ...} and {*n<sub>1</sub>*, *n<sub>2</sub>*, *n<sub>3</sub>*, ...}.

You can take input as 2 lines of input, an array with the two arrays *m* and *n* as its elements, or any other reasonable method of input.

### Output:

A value of *a* such that *sgn(sin(ax))* equals 1 when x = *m<sub>1</sub>*, *m<sub>2</sub>*, *m<sub>3</sub>*, ..., and -1 when x = *n<sub>1</sub>*, *n<sub>2</sub>*, *n<sub>3</sub>*, ...

If no such value of *a* exists, you can output any non-numerical value.

### Test cases:

```
Example inputs will be in the form [[m1, m2, m3, ...], [n1, n2, n3, ...]]
Input                  | Output
[[1, 5],    [2, 3]]    | 1.75
[[2, 3, 6], [5]        | 4.5
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]] | 3.1415925
[[1, 6],    [2, 3]]    | Random junk
[[2, 3, 4], [1]]       | <Anything non-numerical>
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether it is possible to find such a value? If yes, could you please add that to the challenge, if no, then I think this challenge is impossible to solve. Other than that you should probably define what happens for `sign` if the argument is zero. Is it enough if it we get a solution for a finite precision implementation of `sin` (but there would actually be no solution)?

Comment: I guess with a fast enough oscillation, there should be a solution for any data set in which there are not two points of opposite categories with the same x value.

Comment: @flawr When I designed the challenge, I didn't know if there was a solution. But, that's what made it interesting. While actually making the test cases and verifying them, I found a good method of finding possible values, and also test it they exist. However, I thought that it was the analysis of the function that made the challenge interesting, and so I wanted people to find their own methods of finding an answer. I'll maybe add some bounds to where you need to check, but I don't want to just straight up give away a possible answer that everyone will copy.

Comment: @feersum I had previously thought that that was the case, but it turns out that some data sets do not have a solution. I put 2 of them in the test cases section.

Comment: "*Two sets/arrays/lists of numbers*": define *numbers*. All of the test cases use integers, but restricting it to integers vs permitting doubles makes a big difference.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've restricted the inputs to be integers only

Comment: @feersum It is relatively easy to see that the last test case does not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Dodge your death!

### Introduction

"Muhuhuhahahah!" The mad scientist laughs. "You're trapped in my own little game!"

In front of you is a deadly pit of snakes, while behind you is a bottomless chasm. There's no way out, you're stuck!

"Two steps in front of you is the snake pit, and two steps behind you is the chasm. But! Before you move, you MUST write down a sequence of steps, forwards and backwards, and give them to me. But! because I'm feeling a bit *evil* today, I can make you take, instead of every step, every `n`th step, where `n` is less than your sequence length!

Choose wisely, now."

What's the maximum number of steps you can take before your imminent death?

### Task

The intro above is a twist on the [Erdős discrepancy conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_sequence#Erd.C5.91s_discrepancy_problem), which was recently proven true (if you want to understand more about this, go to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFHsrCNtJu4), by James Grime - I "stole" the twist question off of him).

The answer to the intro is `11` steps, but I won't go too in-depth with a proof. The answer, if the distance between you and the two "dangers" were `3` steps, is `1160` steps, although that isn't validated properly yet.

Your task is to make a program that generates the longest sequence of steps you can for a larger `x`, where `x` is the number of steps between you and the two `dangers`. For the purposes of this challenge, `+` represents a step forward, and `-` represents a step back.

So, an output for an input `2` is:

```
+--+-++--++
```

Which works, no matter what `n` the mad scientist chooses. For our challenge, `x = 5`.

### Rules:

- Your entire program should fit into your answer. However, if it doesn't fit, please provide an additional Github repository, or something similar.
- You may update both your answer and program, if you can get a better score via optimisation.
- In your answer, you must have:

  - Your program, in its entirety
  - The amount of steps generated - this will be your final score.

    - You must also provide an online version of the sequence in a Pastebin, or something similar. This is so we can check your answer.
  - The time your final score was last updated, so I don't have to check your history
- You may NOT hardcode sequences beforehand
- Your program must work for all `x` (where `x` is the number of steps between you and the pit & chasm), but you only need to provide the score for `x = 5`.

The answer with the largest score wins!

### Meta:

- What tags should I put in?
- What things should I fix / elaborate?
- For the "link to text file containing sequence" thing, I'm worried that the files might eventually get really big, as answers are more and more sophisticated. Is there any way to counteract that?

Comment: 1. "*Your task is to make a program that generates the longest sequence of steps possible for a larger `x`*" doesn't actually seem to be true: later text implies that you want something that terminates in a reasonable time rather than something which finds the actual optimum. 2. "*The accepted answer will be the answer with the highest score, a week after the challenge is posted*" is something which we've been discouraging for about the past five years. 3. For `n=3` isn't the maximum possible actually `1160`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I got confused with what you meant by 2 for a while... you mean that the answer shouldn't be determined in time at all, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Accept the best answer after a week if you want, but don't imply that there's a deadline to submit answers.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59608/62131). The rules aren't quite the same, but this may nonetheless be similar enough to be a duplicate. Also, "your program must fit into your answer" is a meaningless length restriction; these sequences are highly compressible, so there's no reason not to calculate the best possible answer for n=5, hardcode it, and still have length left for a feeble attempt at other lengths.

Comment: @ais523 The maximum length for `n = 5` is extremely high, though, if I'm not mistaken. That would certainly make it extremely difficult to compress, and even if it was compressed, there's a very high chance of being beaten by some other answer. Also, that challenge's primary goal is code-golf, whereas mine doesn't focus on code golf at all, rather, generating the longest sequence possible. I can make `n` higher if you want.

Comment: @ais523 I got rid of the "program must fit into your answer" thing.

Comment: You go back and forth between `x` being the input and `n` being the input (the number of steps). It'd be better to be consistent. Also, instead of saying your program generates the longest sequence of steps possible, which can't be done because we don't know how long that sequence is, you should instead say that it generates as long a sequence as you can, or something like that.

Comment: @isaacg Fixed both issues!

Answer (score 1):

## Let's not collide

#### *Contextualization*

You might have heard about [Re-Volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Volt), a pretty old video game. Its collision system for cars is somewhat interesting : the body of the vehicle gets transformed into a simplified 3d convex shape which is then filled with spheres.

[image: Example]

#### *Challenge*

Your objective is to produce a code that will, provided a 2d shape and the number of wanted circles, output a similar result to the picture above. That is represent the polygon as accurately as possible with circles.

The two dimensional shape shall be a convex polygon of N vertices. The spheres will of course have the position and the diameter your code defines as optimal.

Your code should be able to take an input representing any irregular convex polygon (the format matters little as long as it can process at least a 10-vertices shape) and an input corresponding to the number of spheres that should fill the polygon.

Because it is impossible to fill completely and perfectly an N-gon with a finite amount of spheres, a tolerance is of course needed so your circles may have a portion (<10%) located outside the polygon. The circles may (and probably should) intersect at some points.

The output must be graphical.

#### *Test cases*

You should test your code with the following three polygons and with 5, 10 and 25 circles.

**Polygon n°1** (10 vertices)

[[1,0],[7.5,0],[15,0],[15.5,1.5],[15,2],[7,4],[4,4],[0.75,2.75],[0,2],[0.25,0.5]]

**Polygon n°2** (5 vertices)

[[0,0],[11,0],[11,2],[7,4],[0,4]]

**Polygon n°3** (8 vertices)

[[1,0],[15,0],[15.5,1],[15,2.5],[10,4.5],[2,4.5],[1,4],[0.5,1]]

#### *Questions*

> • Are the rules and the objectives clear enough ? Does the challenge make sense ?
>
> • How should I define a winner (is a winner mandatory) ?
>
> • Is it a good idea to leave the choice of the input to the coder ?
>
> • Does this challenge already exist and this is a duplicate of some sort ?
>
> • Are there any english mistakes ?
>
> • Is the challenge actually a realistic thing to suggest ?

Any and all suggestions are welcome since this is my first post here.

Comment: It's currently unclear exactly what sort of sphere packings are expected for the inside of the polyhedron; are you just tiling the surface, or the interior too? You also need some sort of objective way to define how well the spheres tile the surface (because people will just submit solutions that don't even try, unless you require them to optimize for that somehow). Generally speaking, the victory condition for this sort of challenge should be code length for an optimal output (if an optimal output is easy), or the best possible output (if an optimal output is hard).

Comment: In terms of English mistakes, you seem to be confusing "polygon" (which is 2-dimensional) with "polyhedron" (which is 3-dimensional), or possibly "circle" with "sphere"; I find it hard to figure out whether the question's asking for a 2D or 3D solution. With respect to input, it's generally best to leave it flexible unless doing so would be exploitable. Also, unless you made the image yourself, you need to give credit to the image creator (and verify that the copyright requirements on the image are suitable).

Comment: @ais523 Thanks for these suggestions. In fact, I was thinking about taking the 3d concept and applying it to 2d. That would translate by "fill the polygon with N circles (disks ?) so that these circles occupy as much surface as possible without them being more than 10% out of the polygon".

Comment: @ais523 Concerning the victory condition, I don't know how to measure the optimality of an output so I guess it'd have to be a code golf.

Finally, regarding the image, I didn't produce the image I use, however, I'm part of the community the image originates from and I'm pretty sure there would be no problems at all. If necessary, I'll add my own or will credit the user (I only know his forum nickname).

Answer (score 1):

## Fairly Cut a Ham Sandwich in Half

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

In this challenge we consider a discrete version of the [ham sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem). In our case the theorem says:

> Given two sets of points in a plane, there is a line that simulaneously bisects both sets.

So given two disjoint sets of distinct integral points in the plane, your task is finding a line of the form `a*x + b*y = c` that bisects these two sets and outputs the integers `a,b,c`.

- Both (strict) half planes have to contain the same number of points of per set.
- The line can contain input points, these are then not counted to either of the sides (e.g. when a set contains an odd number of points, or all points are on one line.)
- The line is not necessarily unique.
- The mentioned representation of a given line is unique up to an
  integral multiple (e.g. `(m*a)*x + (m*b)*y = (m*c)` represents the
  same line as above), but you do not have to output the fully reduced
  form.

#### Examples

As we said above, the output is not necessarily unique, so the presented outputs here are just examples. All the outputs are give in the form `a,b,c`.

```
Input: [(1,2),(1,4),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,4),(4,1),(4,3)] [(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,4),(3,1),(3,3),(4,2),(4,4)]
Output: 410,640,2625 (410x + 640y = 2624)
        1,1,5 (x+y=5)
        0,2,5 (2y=5)
```

In the following we see three valid outputs:

[image]

```
Input: [(1,1),(2,2)] [(1,2),(2,1)]  
Output: 2,5,10 (2x+5y = 10)
```

(more to be added)

Comment: The best solution to this as written is probably brute force (or even randomized brute force, i.e. keep picking random lines until one of them works). You should probably either explicitly allow that, or else design a rule to disallow it.

Answer (score 1):

## Collatz Bearings

Everyone knows the collatz conjecture. It is that this function:

[image: Collatz Conjecture]

when repeatedly applied on a positive non-zero integer will reach one.

There are many ways to visualise this. Inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85731), with the original source of this method [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/38cg9r/a_beautiful_picture_related_to_collatz_conjecture/), this is how we will do it:

Start at 1, with a northward bearing. The next numbers will be one unit (of any, consistent) size, and `x` degrees clockwise (+x) if it is even, and `x` degrees anticlockwise (-x) if it is odd.

An example of this can be seen here (Though it starts with an eastward bearing). It uses a few hundred random starting points and goes backwards. But it's probably easier to build it backwards.

[image: Visualisation of the Collatz conjecture]

Here is a graph-like visualisation, showing the first 8 levels:

[image: First 8 levels]

There can be collisions.

Your task is to take two numbers, which would correspond to 2 nodes on that tree, and return the bearing of the second node to the first node.

### Input

3 numbers. Positive integer `a`, Positive integer `b`, and angle `x`, in any unit you desire. `b > a > 0`, `x` is the angle of seperation, in it's simplest form (mod 360 for degrees, mod 2pi for radians, or having the upper half be negative if you wish.) `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be in different places (e.g., you won't have `a = 20` and `b = 21`.)

### Output

Using the method described above, the bearing of `b` from `a` in the graph, in the units of the input angle.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest program in bytes wins.

#### Note

If the Collatz Conjecture is eventually proven wrong, you do not need to take inputs where repeated application does not reach 1.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: I don't understand what we're supposed to do. If we start at 1 then we'll go `1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1` so we should draw a chain `LLRLLRLLR...`. The supplied image doesn't look like that chain.

Comment: 1 is the starting point. Then you go clockwise up to 2. It's a really zoomed out image, I'll post a zoomed in one with numbers

Comment: I think what's missing is something to say that the iteration is backwards. At least, that's how I can make sense of the graph: "*It uses a few hundred random starting points*" still confuses the issue. "*The bearing of the second angle to the first angle*" is also rather confusing: judging by the *Output* section I think it should be *node* rather than *angle*.

Answer (score 1):

## The Travelling Merchant [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Economy is flourishing in the great Kingdom of Pipysigea `[pee-pee-see-gee-ah]`, since the bandits have been driven away by the King's army.
        Especially, many people have decided to make trade their... trade, and have become **merchants**. You were one of them.
        You used most of your life's savings to purchase a good wagon and some animals of your choice. (Note: it can't be dragons. Sorry.)
        Unfortunately, you have just moved to Pipysigea from far away, attracted by the promises of wealth and security,
        so you don't really know much about the Kingdom: you have just bought a map, so you know the names of the cities
        and where they are, but you don't really know how long it's going to take to travel from one city to another.

So what is your goal? Being a merchant, you'll want to travel from city to city to get an idea of what good they want to buy
        and what goods they sell.

There will be a total of **X** *kinds* of goods in the Kingdom, and each city will be looking to **buy** 3 kinds and will
        be **selling** 3 kinds of goods. You will need to find out whether their prices are good for you:
        for example, the city of *Puzzleon* might be selling *iron* for 4 coins per unit and buying *bread* for 1 coin per unit,
        and the city of *Stackapor* might be selling *wool* for 2 coins per unit and buying *iron* for 5 coins per unit: in this case,
        it would be profitable to buy iron from Puzzleon and then travel to Stackapor to sell it.

But beware: trade is ever-changing, and **prices are going to change** based on what you and other merchants do.
        If you keep selling *iron* in *Stackapor* over and over, their need for it will soon start lowering, and
        so will the price they offer for that good. Similarily, if you buy a lot of *iron* from *Puzzleon*, the quantity at their disposal
        will lower and the amount of **coins** they want for it will start **getting higher**, until they run out of iron and **stop selling it**.

Beware, also, of **taxes**! The arch-enemy of any merchant. Every seven days (= turns) you are going to be taxed,
        based on your current **wealth**, which is measured by actual *coins* and amount of *goods* in your wagon.
        After all, his majesty King Golfus II deserves compensation for ridding the Kingdom of bandits and letting it prosper. And also for having
        established free market, of course.

During your travels, you will eventually **encounter** fellow (or rival, depending on your attitude) **merchants**,
        with whom you can **trade** just like you can with cities. You can decide to keep walking or to stop and trade.
        Every time this happens, you can tell them 1 good you are willing to buy (or none) and the price you offer, 
        and the same with 1 good you are willing to sell.
        The other merchant will do the same. Then, you can respond by accepting or declining both of their proposals or just one.
        They will do the same with your proposals. Once all this is done with, you can resume your travel.

**You lose if you go bankrupt**: that happens when the time comes to pay taxes and you don't have enough coins.
**You** automatically **win** **if all other merchants have gone bankrupt**.

The game ends after **XXX** turns, and the winner will be the merchant with the most **coins**.

---

### Rules

- **Antitrust Law**: a merchant cannot be made specifically to support another merchant. (To help ensure this, merchants can never know the name of the merchant they are trading with)
- **Fair Trade**: a merchant cannot be made specifically to harm the trade of another merchant.
- **Fair Code**: King Golfus II is the one and only ruler, and a merchant may **not** interfere with the law (also known as "The Controller")

---

### Technicalities

You will be provided with a list of **randomly generated cities** (e.g. 10 to 15) with their *coordinates* on the map (a simple cartesian plan with X and Y values).
        The terrain is assumed to be pretty much the same overall, so travel times are based only on distance (initially I thought about giving specific travel costs - e.g. difficulty of road, maybe mountainous or muddy or whatever - to each "link", unbeknownst to the merchant, but felt like it would have complicated things too much. If you think it would be a nice addition, feel free to say it in the comments!)

Every city has a randomly generated list of *3 items to sell and 3 items to buy*. The *quantity* they have available of each item they sell is also randomly generated, as well as the prices of all 6 kinds.
        Obviously, if a city sells iron they won't also be looking to buy it.

**Each merchant** can only be in *one* of these three positions:

- in a city
- on the way from one city to another
- midway between two cities, stopped to trade with another merchant

The game proceeds in rounds, which are made of each player's turn. Every round, the turn order is changed
        (To be decided: poorest players first or randomly generated?)

In their turn, **each player** can do *one* of these things:

- trade with the city, if they are in a city
- trade with a merchant, if they have encountered a merchant on the road
- resume travelling to the other city, if they have encountered a merchant
- start travelling to another city

If, in the previous turn, the player started travelling to another city, at the start of this turn he'll either

- be notified that they have encountered a merchant, and can decide whether to trade or keep walking
- be notified that they have reached the other city, and receive the information about it (its name and its trade prices)

If the player encounters a merchant and decides to keep travelling instead of trading, they will reach the city they were travelling
        to and will still be able to act (= trade with the city or move again)

If, instead, the player trades with the merchant, their turn is considered over and will be able to move again on their next turn (note: since they will be midway between two cities, they will have the chance to decide which of the two to travel to, in case they want to change their previous "travel decision")

Taxation happens at the start of the player's turn, if it is the taxation round (= once every 7 rounds)

> Note: the player can't "talk" to the other merchant unless they both
>   stop to trade, so if the player decides to keep travelling they won't
>   know the other merchant's prices. (I'm not sure about this rule, so
>   please give me feedback :) would it be more sensible to know the other
>   merchant's prices before having to decide whether to stop?)

### Code

I haven't started coding the controller yet, but I was thinking about using Node.js (since javascript is my favourite language, and I don't have tools to use Java and would prefer to avoid having to install stuff) so that bots can be submitted in the form of node modules (either written in javascript or with a javascript wrapper like most low-level node modules)

Note that your bot will be able to save data into a .txt file.

Please give me feedback if you want to suggest a different approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Count Numbers in Integer Partition

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Sandbox Remarks

I'm looking for a description to make the problem more clear.

### Challenge and Example

We can partition a positive integer into smaller (or equal) ones. For instance, for `N=6`, it can be divided into:

- 6 (1 integer occurs >= 1 times, 0 integer occurs >= 2 times)
- 5+1 (2, 0)
- 4+2 (2, 0)
- 4+1+1 (2, 1)
- 3+3 (1, 1)
- 3+2+1 (3, 0)
- 3+1+1+1 (2, 1)
- 2+2+2 (1, 1)
- 2+2+1+1 (2, 2)
- 2+1+1+1+1 (2, 1)
- 1+1+1+1+1+1 (1, 1)

Your task is to work out the sum of the count of integers in each case, which occurs greater or equal than `M` times. In the aforementioned case, if `M=1`, the result is `1+2+2+2+1+3+2+1+2+2+1=19`, and if `M=2`, the result is `0+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+2+1+1=8`.

### Input

Two positive integers `N`, `M`.

`N` is the number being partitioned from.

`M` is the lower limit of occurrences.

### Output

One integer, the sum of the count of unique integers in each partition.

### Remarks

- This is a code-golf so shortest code wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Example I/O

All padding spaces are for formatting on PPCG only. You don't need to take care of them.

```
8  2  => 19
10 1  => 97
25 4  => 1228
25 50 => 0
50 7  => 87004
50 50 => 1
```

All I/O for `M,N<=50`: [here](https://pastebin.com/Yaji6U2j)

Comment: To see whether I've understood this: you want ![\sum_{\lambda \vdash N} \sum_i [a_i \ge M]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEncL.png) where the outer sum is over all partitions of `N`, ![\lambda = 1^{a_1} 2^{a_2} \ldots k^{a_k}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEQL.png) in the frequency representation?

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I understand your equation correctly, in this problem,  `N` should be a sum of smaller integers, instead of a product of smaller ones.

Comment: Yes, it's just that the frequency representation of partitions looks like a product because it's intended to be compact. I think that [OEIS A066633](http://oeis.org/A066633) is the table of desired results, although its description isn't necessarily any clearer.

Comment: Should `5+1` not be `(2,0)`?

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry, yes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry for my not-so-good mathematic. Yes it is A066633. I just come up with the idea when learning Elder's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

## Print all matching leaves [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

In Natural Language Processing, we sometimes interpret sentences as being context-free languages, and therefore as having a certain tree structure, also called constituency trees, or parse trees. These trees are sometimes written down in a notation that (as far as I know) stems from the Penn Treebank project:

A tree is either of:

- `(a b1 b2 b3...)`, with `a` being the tree's label (typically something like `NP` for "noun phrase") and `bn` being the same representation of it's sub-trees (all being non-terminals)
- `(a c)`, which `a` being the tree's label and `c` being the label of a single terminal child (a word).

Valid trees:

- `(S Hi)` (Simple tree containing only one word, "Hi")
- `(A (B (C D)))` (Nested tree containing only one word, "D")
- `(A (B C) (D (E F)) (G H))` (Tree containing the words "C", "F", and "H")

Invalid trees:

- `Hi` (a terminal is not a tree)
- `(A B C)` (terminals have no siblings)
- `((A (B C)))` (extra parantheses)
- `(A (B C)))` (unbalanced parantheses)

For understanding this format better I recommend [this online tool I wrote ages ago](http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de). For example, this is a visualization of the first example case:

[image]

#### Task:

Given a Penn-Treebank-style tree representation and a non-terminal, output the space-seperated concatenation of all leaves for every instance of this non-terminal.

#### Rules:

- You may take the two inputs (tree representation and non-terminal symbol) in any of the standard ways, but always as strings. You may take them in any order.
- The output can be a list of strings (`["The dog", "a cat"]`), some other kind of sequence, a (e.g.) comma-seperated string, and anything else that's reasonable
- Both inputs are guaranteed to never be empty.
- The tree representation input is guaranteed to contain at least one terminal symbol.
- Single spaces may or may not exist for formatting (both the first and the second example are equally valid and both have to be accounted for), but there will always be a single space between a terminal symbol and its immediate parent (e.g. between `Det` and `the` in the first example)
- In case you don't find any matching terminals, you may either raise an error, not output anything, or output some kind of empty sequence.
- All node labels (terminal or not) will match `/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/`.
- Specify which output format you use
- The shortest code (per language) wins

#### I/O examples

```
input 1                                                input 2  output
(S(NP(Det The)(N dog))(VP(V likes)(NP(Det a)(N(cat))))), NP -> "The dog", "a cat"
(NP (Det A) (AP (Adj fancy) (N car))),                   V  -> an empty sequence
(N cat),                                                 N  -> "cat"
```

#### Output format examples

- List of strings: `["The dog", "a cat"]`
- CSV: `"The dog, a cat"`
- CSV without spaces: `"The dog,a cat"`

Comment: I might be confused, but you state the input will be a non-terminal; is `N` not a terminal in the last example? Did you mean input would just be a label, non-terminal or otherwise? Would you mind qualify `(nothing)`, and clarify the output rules: the first example is effectively a list of list, is that the expected output, or should it be a list of strings (space-delimited tokens)?

Comment: @VisualMelon `N` is not a terminal, `cat` is. `(nothing)` is supposed to mean "no or empty output", but I should clarify that and the output rules: Either a list of strings (`["The dog", "a cat"]`) or a something-seperated string (`"The dog, a cat"`). `(nothing)` would mean empty string, empty list, ...

Answer (score 1):

## Obsfucation: Use Uncommon Chars

[obsfucation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obsfucation) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

*Note that I do not have the SE lookup skills to set this up. An automated query would take this challenge a low way. If someone would like this to happen, I would greatly appreciate some help setting this up :)*

[Basic search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aanswer%20%22jelly%22) (currently searches for Jelly, anywhere)

First, choose your language. It must have at least 100 answers on PPCG before the posting of this challenge, and at least 25 chars that are not no-ops. /* Click this query and insert your language's name to see if it is valid. If it is, this query will give you legal chars, and their point value */. Use those chars the complete the challenge. The lowest point value wins.

## /*This Query

//Can we do challenges for SE queries? If so this would be a decent one :)

What I would like for this query to be:

Gets all chars from the first codeblock following the language name in a heading. Accumulates all chars into a frequency table. Make sure that there are at least 25 relevant chars - we can human inspect this to insure no-ops are not polluting the data. It will then return the bottom 20% (frequency) of chars, rounded down, along with point values from 1-length for each of them. The least common chars will receive lower scores. Ties will have the same point value (do it like tournament rankings - `1,1,3`, not `1,1,2`.)

Challenge answerers will only be able to use the chars provided. /*Should whitespace be excluded (and allowed to be used, with a penalty) because of how SE treats whitespace?*/

RE 25 char min: I really would like to get rid of this, but I don't know how else to prevent languages like BF from having an inherent advantage. Even if I restrict BF to 2 chars, it will score really low because they will have point scores `1` and `2`.*/

## /*The Challenge

I have not yet decided what the challenge should be - snippets to solve as many challenges, with point value as tiebreaker, might work, or a more difficult challenge. Input requested :) */

Answer (score 1):

I would like to ask this challenge:

The objective of this programming puzzle is to reproduce the following gif. [image]

However, I do not know the specs for the making of such an animation.

How can I make this a standard/allowed puzzle with this limitation?

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid it's rather unlikely there is any way for this to become an acceptable challenge without you specifying the gif very precisely. You don't really need to know how to make an animation to do that, but you need to be able to accurately describe the shapes involved. You'd also probably need to describe framerate as a minimum, and probably a min/max speed of the dots.

Comment: Seems like a very interesting challenge, but needs quite a few things, including an objective winning criterion and an actual description of the required output.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How would determine the speed of the dots? i.e., what unit should I use? What framerate would advise?

Comment: @MDXF Would smallest answer be a good criterion?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not certain how to approach making the animation smooth by specifying these. However, I do think code-golf is a suitable winning criterion.

Answer (score 1):

### Write a brute-forcer for the 3-byte input 'emoticon numbers' challenge

The [Emoticon numbers!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125455/571) challenge asks you to identify the 3-byte snippet which evaluates to the highest numeric value in your language, and which also has the bytes in the form `ABA` (where the outer two are identical and the middle one is different), and which generates an output that is only digits.

I trust your claim that you have identified the best possible one is honestly intended, but as a casual scripter I'm not totally convinced, and can't be reassured by unfamiliar language specification references - since there are only 256^2 possible values, can you convince me with brute force instead?

Write a program or function which:

1. takes no input
2. generates all the possible 3-byte sequences matching the pattern `ABA` and evaluates them in the same language. (No using one language to generate the best pattern for a different language).
3. Processes all the ones which evaluate to digits-only (output text matches the regex `^[0-9]+$`, with or without trailing newline).
4. Outputs just the `ABA` sequence which evaluated to the highest value, and an optional trailing newline. No errors or stderr output from failed evaluations.

Clarifications:

- There's no limit on runtime, but your program must at least plausibly finish if run for long enough. Particularly, if evaluating one of the byte sequences would get stuck prompting for keyboard input, or go into an infinite loop, or quit the interpreter, you must avoid or handle that.
- If you are able to usefully reduce the search space (and explain why it's valid for your language) to avoid searching 256^2 options, that's OK. Especially if you need to do so to get past an infinite loop, etc.

Show off your brute-force strength by forcing your brute-forcer into the smallest possible space. Fewest bytes wins.

Tag: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: The whole challenge seems really brute-force :))

Comment: I actually did that to prove that `9E9` is the optimal JS solution.

Comment: -100 points if your brute forcer fits `ABA` :D

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there are languages for which some program of the form `ABA` neither halts nor obviously doesn't halt. It's likely too short, but who knows.

Comment: [With no downvotes or critique it's not too badly formed, but with only +1 upvotes it's not popular either so I am not going to post it]

Answer (score 1):

## stdin FPS

Count the input FPS ("F"s per second)

#### Task:

Read a potentially infinite text stream. While you do, display (at least once per second) your FPS, i.e. the amount the characters "f" or "F" appeared.

The FPS has to be accumulated over a time frame of five seconds, meaning you can't just print the number of Fs you've seen this second every second.

#### Rules:

- Standard loopholes are banned
- Read one character (or byte) at a time. If (and only if) your language doesn't have the ability to read characters as they appear in the input, you may read the input one line at a time.
- The FPS display may be in any reasonable format, for example `3.54fps` or `0.9224`
- You may round the resulting numbers to 2 (or more) digits after the decimal point, but no less. Displaying only integers is not allowed.
- To display a new value, you may either:

  - clear the screen before printing a new value,
  - overwrite the existing value,
  - or seperate the values by newline characters
- Be case-insensitive
- In the first second, you don't have to display anything, and if you do, your value doesn't have to be accurate or meaningful.
- Before five seconds have elapsed, you have to average over the total elapsed time since execution started.

#### Sandbox questions:

- Dupes? (I don't know what to search for)

Comment: *"In the first second, you don't have to display anything"* and *"The FPS has to be accumulated over a time frame of at least 5 seconds"* are kind of conflicting. As I understand, we don't have to display anything in the first five seconds...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I will clarify. What I mean is that in the first second you don't have to display anything, after the first second the amount of Fs in the first second, after the second second the average amount of Fs in the last two seconds and so on, until you reach the fifth second, after which you may choose to average only over the last five seconds.

Comment: Also, before posting, I advice you to clarify *"potentially infinite text stream"*... the community will react if you do not specify how the input is specifically taken

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Clarified (and changed) the five seconds rule. What do you suggest regarding the "potentially infinite text stream"? Adding exceptions for memory limits, etc.? Or clarifying again that output has to occur "live"?

Comment: Add both the specs, and wait to see if there are any other suggestion here

Answer (score 1):

## Least Picky Language [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

For this challenge, you will create a programming language that is not picky at all. That is, for any program of any length consisting of any characters in the ASCII range `[32..126]` and any input consisting of any characters in the same range, your program must do something without any errors. The program only has to hypothetically work for any length; that is, StackOverflowException and the like are acceptable if the input or program is too long for your new language to handle (however, I require it to work for program size up to 1024 bytes and input up to 1024 bytes).

In your programming language, no character or combination of characters can be useless (to prevent everything from being a no-op). That means that every character in the program must affect the function somehow, even if the overall function does not change. No two characters can have the same specification either.

For example, it is not allowed to have `-` and `N` both compute the negative of a number.

Note that `<space>` is a valid character in the program and must do something even if it is leading or trailing. Also note that you do not have to handle tabs or newlines in the program or the input.

The most upvoted answer at the end of 2017 Calendar Year (UTC December 31 23:59:59) will be accepted, and I will award a +50 bounty to my personal favorite language.

## Meta

- Duplicate?
- Clear enough validity criteria?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from this... my first thought (since I only usually code-golf) is to just sum the ascii values of the input (i.e. define each char/token as adding the ascii value of the char). There is a very large space of programs that meet these criteria, and I think perhaps this is just too broad.

Comment: @VisualMelon Yes, there are many valid submissions. It's a [tag:popularity-contest] so the one people like most wins. The thing you described would be valid but I doubt people would like it.

Comment: Rather, but I'm wondering what we might expect people to like... there is scope to do virtually anything here (you can even define something that is picky, and just define an output for when it fails). It feels like less of a challenge to achieve something given constraints, and more a challenge to find something amusing, and wrap it up with these constraints.

Comment: @VisualMelon That is largely the challenge; popcons are hard to make nowadays so I expect this to be sandboxed for quite a while. Do you have any ideas for how I could improve the scope of valid submissions? I was thinking requiring Turing Completeness.

Comment: Even if you enforce Turing completeness, someone can make a BF variant, and then define the remaining characters as 'add ascii value to output'. I'm afraid I don't really have any ideas to tighten it up, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @VisualMelon I'll ask in TNB but thanks for noticing the potential issues to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Lots of Pi(e)!

### For Meta:

Any tags other than [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and [pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)?

Dupe?

Any errors?

Clear enough?

### Your Task:

Because everyone likes more pi, we're going to give them 999 decimal digits of it.  Your program should output pi truncated (not rounded off) at 999 decimal places.  For reference, here it is:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859502445945534690830264252230825334468503526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300192787661119590921642019
```

### Input:

None, your program may not take any input at all.

### Output:

Pi truncated at 999 decimal digits.

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte count wins!

Good Luck!

Comment: Closest I could find was [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/506/31625), but this challenge doesn't have the slightly odd restrictions that one does. I don't think I would close it, but I would understand if someone disagreed.

Comment: Usually, we make it so that programs can assume the input is empty, not that we cannot take input. Some esolangs read all the input there is before starting execution.

Comment: yes but this you are not allowed any input

Answer (score 1):

## Sample the Sierpinski traingle

Inspired by [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs).

### Task

Your task is to implement the following method to sample a [Sierpinski triangle](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7-r_bnL_UAhUPYlAKHWbkBkgQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSierpinski_triangle&usg=AFQjCNF0DZo4ztRSSaeJlyyOqXGllzs9hg&sig2=ImsoVr7Kh_UYbybPdCBH0g) and plot all the intermediate steps.

### Method

Given three points `a,b,c` and some starting point `x_0`, for each iteration you sample one of the three points `a,b,c` with equal probability. You then place `x_{i+1}` in the middle of the edge between `x_i` and the sampled point. Repeating this draws the Sierpinski triangle.

### Input

You'll receive the coordinates of the three starting positions through any default accepted input method. The exact format can be flexible: a matrix, a list per point `[xa,ya],[xb,yb],[xc,yc]`, a list for `x` and `y` `[xa,xb,xc],[ya,yb,yc]`, a flat list `[xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc]` are all allowed.

The starting point `x_0` is `[0,0]`. You can assume `[0,0]` would fall within the overall shape.

### Output

For each iteration, including the initial, draw a plot of all the points up to that point. There should at least be a 100ms delay between two plots. If your language does not support graphical displays, you can also write your images to a file.

Since the triangle is an infinite fractal, the program should loop forever (given infinite memory and all that jazz).

### Criteria

Shortest code wins!

### Example code (R)

```
Sierpinski <- function(p, q) {
  x11()
  par(mar = rep(0, 4))
  plot(p, q, col= "red", pch = 15, cex = 1, axes = FALSE)

  x <- 0
  y <- 0

  repeat {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    n <- sample(1:3, 1)
    x <- floor(x + (p[n] - x) / 2)
    y <- floor(y + (q[n] - y) / 2)
    points(x, y, pch = 15, cex = 0.5)
  }
}
```

[image]

## Meta

- Duplicate? There are a couple 'draw a sierpinski triangle' challenges, but I couldn't find any that use this method of drawing them.
- Is the specification of the algorithm clear enough or should I add pseudocode?
- Is the 100ms delay between iterations reasonable?

Comment: What do you guys think? Is this sufficiently different from this existing one (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38173/play-the-chaos-game)?

Mine adds actually showing the animation of the game in progress, but I am not sure if that is different enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Beat the turing test [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Both you and your bot have to connect to a speed dating chatroom (details below) where you will either be paired up with another bot, or with another human. You get 30 seconds to converse with your partner before you are disconnected, and are presented with the choise of wether you think the person you spoke with is a human or not.

This process will be repeated in a round robin fashion for a maximum of 10 minutes, or until everyone has spoken with everyone.
You will not be paired with your own bot.

You will be given an equal number of votes for human/robot, as you will be facing an equal number of each. Both you and your bot will be given the option to change these after the conversations.

### Scoring

Robots get 2 point for fooling a robot, and 5 points for fooling a human. Humans are not awarded any points for correct guesses, but lose 2 points if they are wrong.

### Rules

- Bots may the internet aswell as external datafiles
- Gentleman's rule: Please do not pretend to be a robot. If every human said nothing but `Beep beep, I am a robot` it would ruin the challenge for everyone.

### Meta

This will be a one-time event on a specific date. There will be a webapp for humans and an API for bots. Until the final date there will be a sandbox site online for testing purposes. I am still undecided on the specifics of the API, and on how long the timespan between posting the challenge and running it should be.

I can also run (some) bots locally, communicating on stdin/stdout

Comment: Can't a human just accuse everyone of being a robot, thus preventing points from being gained?

Comment: I suspect that participation in this will be very low (as it's a highly difficult task), which is a problem for a challenge that inherently has a deadline. Stack Exchange might not be the best place to run this.

Comment: @NeilA. You are absolutely right. I think my new scoring system fixes that, but ultimately I rely on participants being honest to make this a fun challenge, which is why I think Stack Exchange is a good place to do this

Comment: 1. Timezones are an issue. 2. You need to clarify the sequence. Do I have to call bot/human immediately after the conversation, or do I have all the conversations first and then call? 3. I suspect that even the recently raised 60k character limit to answers could be a problem for writing a sophisticated bot. Can answers use additional data files stored somewhere public such as github?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think allowing you to change votes at the end would make programming bots more fun because you can compare the conversations against each other to determine humaness. Nice point

Answer (score 1):

## Repetitive Primes [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

A [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) in any base `B` is a number consisting solely of 1s in that base.

Your task is to figure out if a repunit of length f `N` in base `B` is a prime number.

## Rules

- `N >= 2`
- `B >= 1`
- `N` and `B` may be taken in any order and in any reasonable method.
- Output a consistent value to indicate primeness and a different consistent value to indicate compositeness.
- Programs and functions are acceptable.
- This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes apply

## Test cases

```
B, N => Result

2, 7 => prime
1, 97 => prime
10, 19 => prime

9, 11 => composite
20, 10 => composite
7, 23 => composite
```

---

### Meta questions

- Dupe? Unclear? Too broad? etc.
- Would this be a better question with a different winning criterion such as [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)?
- Should I change the title?
- Any other constructive criticisms?

Comment: I don't think [tag:fastest-code] would be a good fit, [tag:code-golf] should work just fine. You can also add [tag:base-conversion] and [tag:decision-problem]. I suggest appending "Primes" to the title.

Comment: 1. "*repunit consisting of `N` in base `B`*" feels to me as though it's missing *`1`s*, although perhaps a better phrasing would be "*repunit of length `N` in base `B`*". 2. Although it's easy to show that `N` must be `1` (which is not valid input) or prime, the test cases should still include at least one where `N` is composite.

Comment: @Laikoni: I agree it might be an interesting code-golf question, but I also want to see people use cool optimizations such as the length must be prime, or base 9 doesn't have any repunit primes, etc. as opposed to everyone using a base conversion followed by slow trial division.

Comment: Slow trial division? Golfing languages will use the `isPrime` builtin, which probably uses BPSW or Miller-Rabin with carefully selected bases.

Comment: This is actually relatively simple to solve. You just need to check whether `((N + 1) % B) == 0`

Answer (score 1):

## Monopoly KoTH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

> This is going to take me a while to finish and may never be fully done. Don't expect this to be posted anytime soon. However, this will be an ongoing project under development.

---

Who hasn't heard of Monopoly? If not, don't worry, as I will explain the rules! If you already know the rules, read on, for they may be different in this rendition.

## The Rules of Monopoly

Monopoly is played on a board, with 36 different squares, that looks somewhat like this

[image: monopoly board]

For this version, we'll use the original British version, because I'm British and proud of it!

Squares are split into 3 categories:

- **Property**. These are the ones with a coloured bar at the top, such as `Old Kent Road` or `Whitehall`. They also include the 4 stations in the middle of each side, and the utilities (`Electric Company` and `Water Works`)
- **Bonus Cards**. These are the squares marked `Community Chest` or `Chance`. These allow for a player to either receive or lose money, depending on a random card choice.
- **Special Squares**. These are the 6 other squares in the board, the 4 corner squares and the taxes (boo!)

Let's look at these categories in a bit more detail.

### Property

Properties are grouped, depending on the colour of said property. Each property has a `rent` value that contains the amount that a player must pay to the owner of the property, when they land on that property. If one player owns all of the properties in one colour, the rent for each is doubled.

Players can also buy properties, which is how they own them. Each property also has a price, which is then deducted from the buyer's cash and given to the Bank, in exchange for the property. Stations cost £100 each and all other properties available to buy have their cost written below their square.

Stations' rent increases the more stations that someone owns. In the following progression

- 1 Station: Rent = £25
- 2 Stations: Rent = £50
- 3 Stations: Rent = £100
- 4 Stations: Rent = £200

Utilities' rent depends on the dice roll. If a player owns 1 utility, multiply the roll by 4 and that is the rent. If the player owns both, multiply the roll by 10 to get the rent due.

Properties can be built on. That means that a player builds houses and hotels on them, in order to increase that properties rent. A player can build houses and hotels on a property if

- it has a coloured bar at the top
- the player owns all of the properties in the group
- they have enough money. Each house costs £50 and each hotel costs £100.

Each property can have a maximum of 4 houses. After that, the player must build a hotel. A property can only have 1 hotel on it. Houses and hotels drastically increase the rent of a property, for example £4 (no buildings) to £450 (one hotel).

### Bonus Cards

The name of these are a bit of a misnomer. These are denoted on the board by `?` symbols and chests on squares and can either give or take money from you. For this game, we will ignore `Get Out of Jail Free` cards and the `Goto` cards. The cards can result in a random integer between `-1000` and `1000` added to your score. If this results in **bankruptcy** (we'll see this later), so be it.

### Special Squares

- **Go**. If you land on Go, you get given a £400 reward. If you simply go past it (Mayfair -> Old Kent Road), you get £200. It's also where the pieces begin.
- **Jail**. If you roll and land on this square, don't worry, as you don't go to jail. You are "Just Visiting"
- **Free Parking**. This is where the taxes go! If you have to pay taxes, either because of the Tax squares or because of a Bonus Card, that money goes to Free Parking. If a player lands on it, they get all the money there!<sup>1</sup>
- **Go to Jail**. This does what it says on the tin. You go straight to Jail. But this time, you're in Jail, not just visiting. You stay in Jail until you roll a double.<sup>1</sup> After which, game continues as normal. You cannot collect rent while in Jail.
- **Taxes**. Super Tax and Income Tax are two squares which charge you £100 and £200, respectively. However, you can regain that money as it goes straight to Free Parking!

### Bankruptcy

In Monopoly, if you run out of money, you are bankrupt. Here, you have two options. You can either mortgage your properties or, if you don't have any, you are out of the game! The last one with any money wins the game and the KoTH!

When you lose, all your properties go to the player who bankrupted you. If that's the Bank by virtue of Bonus Cards, then all your properties are available to be bought again.

### Mortgage

You can mortgage properties in order to get more money if you're in a pinch. Unfortunately, this "deactivates" the property, meaning that you don't get any rent when people land on it. If you have enough money, you can unmortgage a property for 110% of its mortgage value. (£100 -> £110)

### Auctions

If you land on an unbought property and don't buy it, either because you don't have enough or you just don't want to, the property goes on auction. This means that all players can bid on the property. Bidding starts at £1, which means that a player can, theoretically, get the property for a much lower or higher price than its original price.

### Trading

I am hoping to be able to include trading but this does depend on my ability as a coder. In an ideal world, I will be able to get it working but, unfortunately, this may not happen :(

<sub>1: I am aware that this changes depending on who you're playing with, but this is how we'll do it in this version.</sub>

## Rules of the KoTH

I have written (still finishing) a `Player` class in Python which contains all of the things that a Monopoly player can do. Your task is to rewrite 2 of the functions that can change your player's behaviour.

While thinking about how to make this KoTH, I listed out the complete process that gives you a chance to change what you do. Let's go over that process! [This flowchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/93771b77-2c00-422d-94c1-33c280129c8c) shows the process for each turn. Green items show the choices that you have to make.

This is the text version:

```
1. Roll dice and move
2. Is the property owned by the Bank?
    1. Yes. Nothing happens.
    2. No. Pay the due rent.
3. Choice of:
    1. Buy
    2. Auction
4. Choice of:
    1. Trade
    2. Build
    3. Mortgage
    4. Unmortgage
    5. Move On
5. Repeat until bankrupt

Auction

1. Choice of:
    1. Play the auction
    2. Don't play the auction
2. Are you playing the auction?
    1. Yes.
        1. Choice of:
            1. Bid new max
            2. Skip one round
            3. Skip all rounds
            4. 'All in'
        2. Repeat until 1 player left bidding
    2. No. Don't do anything.

Trade

1. Choose a player to trade with
2. Offer properties and/or money
3. Does the other player agree with the trade options?
    1. No. They counter offer. Do you like their options?
        1. No. Do you want to continue negotiating?
             1. Yes. Go to point 2 above
             2. No. The trade is over.
        2. Yes. You trade the agreed upon items.
    2. Yes. You trade the agreed upon items
```

But, for you coders out there, I'll explain using a bit of code.

Your submission should contain a single class that inherits from `Player`. You may add in as many extra attributes as you want, but in order to be used, *your* code must refer to them. I'm not editing the controller just for your bot to work.

However, each class must look like this

```
class NameOfPlayer(Player):
    def turn(self, square, roll):
        (code that determines your actions per turn)
    def auction_action(self, price, bidders):
        (code that determines your auction actions)
    def trade_actions(self, players, last_offer):
        (code that determines your trading actions)

    (any other functions you want)
```

Your `turn` function will return 3 numbers as a list e.g. `[1,2,3]` which are the results of the choices above. The first item should be either `1` or `2` (Buy or Auction), the second should be one of `1`,`2`,`3`, `4` or `5` (of the `4. Choice of:` options) and the third should be either `1` (play the auction) or `0` (don't play the auction) such as `[1,5,0]` would buy the property, move on to the next player and not play the auction on this turn (doesn't matter as there wasn't an auction).

Your `auction_action` function will return either a number (your bid) or one of `a` (all in), `s` (skip this round) or `q` (quit auction), which determines what you will do on that round of the bidding. This continues until either you quit the auction of you are the only one left.

Your `trade_actions` function will return a list every time it is called. The list consists of `[agree with previous offer (as a bool), properties to trade (as a list), cash to trade (as an int)]`. When a trade has just begun, the first item in the list will be ignored and the `last_offer` parameter will be ignored. The `last_offer` parameter contains the second 2 items returned by the person you are negotiating with, so that you can decide whether you want to continue trading or not.

If you lose all your money, your program with be taken out of the active players and placed into the results table. The last one standing wins!

Comment: I call dibs on the Go submission that always go to jail.

Comment: While you are allowed to use the monopoly rules, I'm not sure about using the picture of the board?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon what do you mean?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is a variant which doesn't allow trading properties, and that's the most interesting part of the game. The rules stated also fail to state what happens to the properties of a player who goes bankrupt. (Correct answer: they must mortgage all of them and then forfeit them to the player to whom they owe rent. I'm not sure offhand what happens if they're going bankrupt due to taxes, but presumably the properties revert to the bank and when someone lands on them they buy or auction).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm currently writing the controller and a base class, which will determine what I can and can't allow in the game. Once that's finished and all issues with the controller are sorted out, I will update the rules here to fit with it's capabilities. Also, the version I've played allows for a player to mortgage their properties to avoid bankruptcy (as in you mortgage and if you're still bankrupt, you lose)

Comment: My point is that unless it's a two-player game, *you lose* is not a sufficient description because the game needs to continue until there's only one winner. The comment about mortgaging is because if I owe you more money than I can get by mortgaging all my properties, I have to mortgage them and give you the money obtained and the mortgaged properties, and so *you* have to pay to unmortgage them before you can benefit from them.

Comment: What stops this from going into an infinite loop without a winner

Comment: Feedback copied from TNB: I think this would be way more interesting if the Goto cards were included, and the random amount given/taken was less significant (£1000 is a lot). The Goto cards add a bit of strategy in which properties to buy. Also, my version has the income tax be either £200 or 10% of the player's net worth. Is that different in yours, or is it just removed for simplicity?

Answer (score 1):

## Mutation-hardening quine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task is to make a program that prints out its own output.

"Hey, we already have this challenge, and tons of variations of it! Why are you making another one?" you may ask, but this one is going to be one of the most difficult ones.

Your quine must be "mutation-hardened", which means the quine still must work, even after any one of its characters is duplicated in place.

For example, if you have a program:

```
abcd
```

These programs must all output `abcd`:

```
aabcd
abbcd
abccd
abcdd
```

(In each of those programs, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are each duplicated in-place, which means the duplicated character was placed directly after the original character.)

### Rules:

- Standard quine rules apply.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Meta:

- Is this challenge too hard?
- What other rules should I put up?

Comment: Is this even *possible*?

Comment: For hard problems, try to find at least one solution.

Comment: @Shelvacu [It doesn't have to be](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life)

Answer (score 1):

## Make a Quiz Parser [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Your task is to create a program that will take an input of multiple 4-choice questions (A, B, C, D) in the format shown below, display each question (format also shown below) and its 4 answer choices, get the user's answer to each question, and, at the end of the quiz, output their score as a percentage.

---

### The Format

#### Questions in input

```
Q<space><Insert question here>:<Insert letter of correct answer here>
<indent 1 space>A<space><answer choice text>
<indent 1 space>B<space><answer choice text>
<indent 1 space>C<space><answer choice text>
<indent 1 space>D<space><answer choice text>
<you can add a newline between questions if it makes things easier>
```

#### How to output questions

```
<question number>. <question>
  A. <answer choice A>
  B. <answer choice B>
  C. <answer choice C>
  D. <answer choice D>
<2 spaces before each answer letter>
```

#### How to output scores

```
Your score is: <score here>%
```

---

### Test Case

```
Q What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?:B
 A African or European?
 B 22 mph
 C I don't know that!
 D What?
```

If this were question number 42, it would output like this:

```
42. What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
  A. African or European?
  B. 22 mph
  C. I don't know that!
  D. What?
```

---

As usual, standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden*.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: I like this challenge, but I think it could use a complete test case

Comment: @musicman523 Ok. I will use an output from fotoforensics for example.

Answer (score 1):

**The task**

Your code should take in an integer `0  < x < 1965593254291461501637330902918203684832716283083` and output the smallest integer `m` such that `x^m mod  1965593254291461501637330902918203684832716283083 = 1`. This long number is the next prime after `2^100` so can be encoded efficiently.

You may take the input in any format that is convenient and output in any convenient form too.

Your code should take less then one minute to run on a standard desktop no matter what the input.

**Examples**

```
2, 4235851503548771316711413838489497242205033676
3, 16943406014195085266845655353957988968820134704
169434060141950852668456553539579889688, 16943406014195085266845655353957988968820134704
```

Those with python or similar can check the answers with e.g. `pow(3,16943406014195085266845655353957988968820134704, 1965593254291461501637330902918203684832716283083)` which equals `1`.

You may not use any builtin or library function which solves this problem for you.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Is there a reason you picked that specific number?

Comment: I think that unless there's a simple formula that gets that number, hardcoding that value would take more bytes than the rest of the code.

Comment: @Phoenix I added a simple formula.

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to use nubmers that are so large that many languages require special constructs to represent them, it gives an unfair advantage to languages with arbitrary precision integers, which already tend to be shorter.

Comment: @Phoenix I take your point but the point of this challenge is to devise efficient  code for large inputs.  Languages with builtin large number support tend  to be quite slow (e.g. python) compared to e.g. C.  I would like to leave it like this.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to find the multiplicative order modulo a prime of a number, short of factoring p-1?

Comment: @xnor, none known.

Comment: @PeterTaylor  Is 100 bits too big to factorize without calling library code to do it for you?  Or could the question allow you to factorize the number beforehand? (Wolfram alpha will do that for free for example for the number in my question minus 1.)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am just wondering how much I need to reduce the number by. Currently it is 160 bits.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually even the command line tool `factor` can handle the 160 bit number it turns out

Answer (score 1):

For technical reasons, many languages have a boundary for number values, which calls for workarounds when operating with numbers outside this range.

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a program which is able to multiply two arbitrary large numbers, given an infinite amount of time and memory.

The input will always be two positive decimal integers in any reasonable format (string, list of digits..)

The output should be (exclusively, apart from any whitespace) the exact decimal product of these integers.

- If integer magnitude is unbounded in your language, you must set an own limit
- The algorithm has to be written individually. If your language has arbitrary multiplication implemented in any way, (built-in, native support) the program has to be written in a way that assumes that these methods are limited to some number
- Note that properties like .length can exceed the integer limit. You can't e.g. ordinarily loop over the digits in a 'for' loop
- A valid solution can not be confirmed by solely test cases but only by analysis of the code
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes per language wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 5378877047254281056308179853217614491205392080414948189690882584626258197090299384248418705254284062330999044417502407170242320748022675887850236280535223588025381434803683717318134517400400886554441
>
> and
>
> 24585803251446564673599904286559945882543472174090101020256415987852946031712809185990398899511551226915139170857973433130460342507187447589801052724967977799120438910759846107262285707877865565231049

Output:

> 13224401279751560029079048725841743388456506005068978434329060038933262717486337348174589758627669812502604130373896959848172091197634331942663385472131265201616801014468642971825909208942693284219016467181922385520740594984640977937358293657922369959902120240111214073507556243844128492765568914803850594686913014876111459929738682018339519061223975139325785119259348090888269287247476161682038609

## Sandbox

Is this different enough from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/long-multiply-8-bits-at-a-time) challenge?

Would this be better suited for [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)?

Comment: The solutions to this will be very interesting.  Looking forward to it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your first bullet point... is it disallowing using the `*` operator in languages with unbounded ints? Would it disallow java's `BigInteger::multiply`? (Java is perhaps a special case, as `int` and `BigInteger` are separated. Furthermore, `BigInteger` is not a "native" implementation). If you want to disallow builtin solutions, say so... but as it stands I think that `java.math.BigInteger::multiply` would be a perfectly valid solution... no?

Comment: @socraticPhoenix Good point, I've edited the post. Is it clearer now?

Comment: "*Note that properties like .length are also bounded numbers, and the input can have infinitely many digits*". What I'm getting is that no-one should bother attempting to answer, because properties like pointers to memory are also finite and so no program will be able to read the input.

Comment: Note also that long multiplication [has been done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2009/194)

Comment: @peter You're right. I made an edit, does it make sense now? Basically it should implement multiplication to the highest magnitude possible for each language. Since memory isn't limited, pointers can always be incremented until input end.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense now, and I don't think there's any way of writing it which would make sense. Either you have loops which don't bother with an index (i.e. most golfing languages), in which case limitations on `length` are both nonsensical and irrelevant; or you need to index into the data structure, in which case your index is subject to the same limitations as `length` and it's completely impossible. I also think that "*reasonable format*" directly contradicts limits on `length`.

Comment: @peter The limitation is not imposed by me. If the program can multiply integers whose length (number of digits) is larger than the INT_MAX (or whatever limit is set), it goes.

Answer (score 1):

## Escape the Labyrinth!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

### Introduction

You are stuck in a labyrinth. You only have your brain and a map. Now you need to find a way out, of course your brain doesn't have much memory (or else you wouldn't be stuck!) so you need to optimize your mental code for size. Of course we can't trivially program in the brain-language, so your brain will also accept any other language.

### Specification

#### Input

Your input will be a Matrix. You may encode it however serves your language best as long as the format doesn't encode additional information. For the purpose of this challenge I will use a list of lists for representation and explanation.

Said matrix will contain four distinct values:

- `0`: This marks a spot you can move onto
- `1`: This marks a wall
- `2`: This marks the starting point
- `3`: This marks the target point

It is guaranteed that there will be exactly one occurence of type-3 and type-2. You may also change the above values / data-types to your liking as long as you don't encode additional information.

It is guaranteed that you will get an input that has a solution. If the input doesn't have a valid solution, the behavior is left undefined. Your program may not terminate, it may error out, it may simply return nothing, it may blow up, it may become a political activist or it may do something else.

You may assume that the input labyrinth is walled-off, that is you can't actually "leave" the labyrinth.

#### Output

Your output will be sequence of four different values:

1. `L`: Stands for left
2. `R`: Stands for right
3. `U`: Stands for Up
4. `D`: Stands for Down

You may change the values and data types of the above constants to your liking, as long as you document these changes and you can uniquely infer the path.

#### What to do?

Given the labyrinth, start your virtual character at the position tagged `2` and find a way to the position tagged `3`. You may not pass through walls (`1` cells) and you may only go one step up, left, right or down in each step. You also need to document your action of course in each step, ie output it as described above.

Note: You do not have to find the *shortest* path, but rather *a* path.

#### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins! Standard [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/55329) apply of course. Standard [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/55329) also apply.

### Example

```
[ 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,2,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
]
```

might result in:

```
Going right.
Going down.
Going down.
Going right.
Going down.
Going down.
Going down.
Going right.
Going right.
Going up.
Going right.
Going right.
Going down.
Going down.
```

Comment: Potential questions: What other tags to use? Should it be allowed to receive position information of `2` and `3` in the input as well?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this wasn't a duplicate. I'm stuck on mobile for quite a while, but My car only turns right is very similar except you have to manage orientation. I'd look closely at other maze challenges to see that this adds to the site.

Comment: I agree with FryAmTheEggman.  This is very likely a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

### ASCII Art Turtle

As you know, the LOGO programming language allows you to manoeuvre a turtle and draw lines in a graphical way. It occurs to me that we can do this for [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art).

A minimal set of commands to produce [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) would be the R(otate right), F(orward) and P(en) commands. For example, the string `FPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPFPRRRFRRRRPF` would produce the following output:

```
\|/
- -
/|\
```

However that AAT code is rather inconvenient so I have chosen the following slightly more compact instruction set:

- `F` Move one cell in the current direction. Initially the current direction is east. If the pen is down, the cell just vacated is set to one of `-/|\` appropriately.
- `B` Move one cell in the reverse direction. (Initially this would be west, of course.) The cell vacated is set in the same way as for `F` (since the output characters are all symmetric).
- `R` Rotate right 45°. Only the current direction changes; nothing is drawn and the current position does not move.
- `L` Rotate left 45°. Otherwise as per `R`.
- `D` Lower the pen. Note that the pen starts lowered.
- `U` Raise the pen.

The above image could therefore be drawn using the command string `BULFDBULFDBULFDBULFDBULFDBULFDBULFDB`, while the string `LFFUBRFDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFRFFRFBRRFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUBLLFDFFBLLFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUBRRFDFRRFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFURBDBBUFLBDBBBBBBBBBLLFFFURBDBBBUFRBDBBBLBB` should hopefully produce this somewhat familiar picture:

```
 /-----------------\ 
/                   \
---------------------
|                   |
---------------------
|                   |
---------------------
\                   /
 \---------|  /----/ 
           | /       
           |/
```

Your function or program must take input as a string, or whatever the nearest equivalent is in your language, and output a newline-delimited or newline-terminated string. (For those of you used to using TIO it should be possible to paste the raw string into the ▼ Input field and show the output directly in the ▼ Output field.) Extra blank rows or columns are not allowed, but you are allowed to pad all the lines to the length of the longest non-blank line. You can take input in lower or mixed case if you prefer. You can assume that the input will only use those six letters. You can further assume that `U` and `D` commands alternate. You can also assume that you will never write in the same place twice.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: The reverse of this could be interesting as a [tag:metagolf]

Answer (score 1):

## An order of primeness

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

### Introduction

In a [recent question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/130390/30013) the concepts of super-primes were explored. A super-prime is a prime whose index is also a prime.

- 2 is *not* a super-prime, its index is `1`
- 3 is a super-prime, its index is `2`
- 5 is a super-prime, its index is `3`
- 7 is *not* a super-prime, its index is `4`
- ...

The first few of these super-primes are `3`, `5`, `11`, `17`, `31`, `41`, `59`, ...

Let us call these primes of at least order 2, because they are more prime than regular primes (which are only of order 1).

Primes of order of 3 or greater can be defined similar. A prime is of order 3 if its index is a prime of order 2.

The first few of the primes at least of order 3 are `5`, `11`, `31`, `41`, `59`, `127`, `179`, `277`, ...

This is sequence [A049076](https://oeis.org/A049076). It was defined by Neil Fernandez in 1999. More information can be found in his [Exploring Primeness Project](http://borve.org/primeness/FOP.html).

### Task

Given a prime, return its order.
More formally

- **INPUT**: A single integer which is guaranteed to be a prime
- **OUTPUT**: A single integer which is the order of the input.
- You can either return or print the result.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

### Testcases

```
           2 ->  1
           3 ->  2
           5 ->  3
           7 ->  1
       52711 ->  9
435748987787 -> 11 (happens to be the 11. Prime of order 11)
```

## Sandbox Questions

1. Does it need any more clarification?
2. Should I define order 0 (not a prime) and allow any number as input, or would that over-complicate the challenge?
3. Primes of higher order tend to get big very fast. Should I somehow specify that a language only has to work for test-cases it can actually handle or is their a consensus already?
4. Is the introduction too big?

Comment: This is just a loop round the linked question, and as such qualifies as a duplicate for the purposes of this site.

Comment: I think this might be an interesting question.

Comment: Last test case -> 10  (or all the other cases ->+1)

Answer (score 1):

### These are two separate challenges.

---

## Convert to mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ

Related: [Convert from mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13277/43319) and [Convert to and from the factorial number system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/convert-to-and-from-the-factorial-number-system).

Given a non-negative real number (no greater than 1×10<sup>40</sup> or the biggest your language can comfortably accommodate, whichever is less) convert it to mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ using the base-36 digits [0-9A-Z] or [0-9a-z] with no leading zeros (except for values smaller than 1). Any reasonable rounding is fine.

#### Examples

`0` → `0` (**0** × !1)
`1` → `1` (**1** × !1)
`2` → `10` (**1** × !2 + **0** × !1)
`3` → `11` (**1** × !2 + **1** × !1)
`4` → `20` (**2** × !2 + **0** × !1)
`42` → `1300` (**1** × !4 + **3** × !3 + **0** × !2 + **0** ×!1)
`100` → `4020` (**4** × !4 + **0** × !3 + **2** × !2 + **0** ×!1)
`12345` → `2304111`
`4294967295` → `8B6570020211`
`10000000000` → `17A5726651220`
`18446744073709551615` → `7BC43F35350835000211`
`0.5` → `0.1`
`0.333333333333333333` → `0.02`
`0.25` → `0.112`
`0.1` → `0.0022`
`5.125` → `21.003`
`2.718281828459045235` → `1.111111111111111111`
`0.001388888888888889` → `0.00001`

---

## Convert from mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ

Related: [Convert to mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13277/43319) and [Convert to and from the factorial number system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/convert-to-and-from-the-factorial-number-system).

Given a string (no longer than 71 characters or the maximum that gives a result your language can comfortably accommodate, whichever is less) convert it from mixed-base mixed-radix ZYX…432.234…XYZ using the base-36 digits [0-9A-Z] or [0-9a-z]. Any reasonable rounding is fine.

#### Examples

`0` (**0** × !1) → `0`
`1` (**1** × !1) → `1`
`10` (**1** × !2 + **0** × !1) → `2`
`11` (**1** × !2 + **1** × !1) → `3`
`20` (**2** × !2 + **0** × !1) → `4`
`1300` (**1** × !4 + **3** × !3 + **0** × !2 + **0** ×!1) → `42`
`4020` (**4** × !4 + **0** × !3 + **2** × !2 + **0** ×!1) → `100`
`2304111` → `12345`
`8B6570020211` → `4294967295`
`17A5726651220` → `10000000000`
`7BC43F35350835000211` → `18446744073709551615`
`0.1` → `0.5`
`0.02` → `0.333333333333333333`
`0.112` → `0.25`
`0.0022` → `0.1`
`21.003` → `5.125`
`1.111111111111111111` → `2.718281828459045235`
`0.00001` → `0.001388888888888889`

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)[factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial)

Comment: I think this is ready.

Comment: I'd like this more with a list of digits 0-35 in the factorial base rather than including letters.

Comment: @xnor Interesting. In that case, there should be no specific upper limit, right?

Comment: @Adám That's right, unless you want a limit for the sake of languages' number bounds.

Comment: @xnor I assume that's covered by default rules. This simplifies the challenge text, so I'll make the change. Thanks

Comment: @xnor How is this?

Comment: @Adám Looks good to me. Is your plan to post a challenge for just one direction?

Comment: @xnor Uh, did you read the post?

Comment: @Adám Yes, and I'm not sure if your plan is to post two challenges, or just whichever direction is more interesting.

Comment: @xnor Two challenges. However, I just noticed that factoradic can easily represent floats too, so should I extend/modify the challenges to that? It would certainly make them different from the existing one.

Comment: Yes, you should do that so built-ins won't be useful (*cough* Jelly *cough*) in addition to distinguishing this from the existing challenge.

Comment: The original challenge with letters was way better...

Comment: I actually agree with @Jenny_mathy because languages like Jelly naturally output different bases in a list format, rather than a string of letters.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Like this?

Comment: @Zacharý Ping ^

Comment: Now it is certainly not a dup.

Comment: Why all the downvotes, just because there's no builtin?

Comment: @Zacharý All one? Anyway, I'll leave it here over the weekend.

Comment: I thought it was two people downvoting rather than just one person changing from upvote to downvote.

Comment: I think you should give an example for 0.5-> 0.1 in the form 4 → 20 (2 × !2 + 0 × !1)

Comment: Also, you should add an example where a digit other that 0-9 appears after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## Stitch the Genome

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [bioinformatics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

#### Introduction

As you probably know DNA (deoxyribonucleic acid) is made up of *bases*, often denoted as A T C and G. One of the coolest things we can do with DNA is sequence it, or figure out what sequence of base pairs make up the molecule. Sequencing small molecules of DNA is easy, but it is hard to sequence long strands without error. Instead, the long strands are copied many times, then cut up into many little pieces. Those pieces are then fed through the sequencer. What we end up getting are many, many sets of pieces of the strand. In each set, we are near-guaranteed to get every base in the strand, but they aren't in any order. The solution, then, is to compare all of the different sets of strand pieces we have, and try and figure out how to put them together.

### Challenge

Your challenge is, given a set of strand pieces, output a possible sequence of the original strand. To simplify real life a bit, you can expect that each set will always contain the entire strand sequence (not in order, mind you), and that there will be at least one possible sequence. Observe a simple example:

```
Input:
 - [ATC, G]
 - [CG, AT]
Output: ATCG
```

From the first input, we deduce two possibilities: `ATCG` and `GATC`. From the second input, we deduce another two possibilities: `CGAT` and `ATCG`. As you can see, the only common possibility is `ATCG`, and thus that is our answer. Let's look at another example:

```
Input:
 - [AT, G, C]
 - [A, TG, C]
Output: ATGC or CATG
```

Here, we deduce six possibilities from the first input: `ATGC`, `ATCG`, `GATC`, `GCAT`, `CATG` and `CGAT`. Then, from the second input, we deduce another six possibilities: `ATGC`, `ACTG`, `TGAC`, `TGCA`, `CTGA` and `CATG`. Since there are two common possibilities, `ATGC` and `CATG`, we can output either one.

Essentially, this problem can be reduced to: `find a common permutation of the input`.

#### Specifics

- You may write a program or function
- You may input in any acceptable format (array of arrays, list of lists, separated string, etc.). Furthermore, you may substitute `A` `T` `C` and `G` in your input with any other unique values, as long as you're consistent
- You may output in any acceptable format
- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

#### Test Cases

Format:

```
Input:
 - Pieces 1
 - Pieces 2
 - Etc.
Possible Outputs: [Possible output 1, possible output 2, etc.]
```

---

```
Input: 
 - [G, A, C, C, T, A, G]
 - [GAC, C, TAG]
 - [G, AC, CT, AG]
 - [GA, CC, T, A, G]
Possible Outputs: [GACCTAG]

Input: 
 - [G, C, G, C]
 - [G, C, GC]
 - [G, CG, C]
Possible Outputs: [GCCG, CGCG, GCGC, CGGC]

Input: 
 - [TA, A]
 - [TA, A]
 - [T, AA]
Possible Outputs: [TAA]

Input: 
 - [CC, T, A]
 - [CC, T, A]
 - [C, CT, A]
Possible Outputs: [CCTA, ACCT]

Input: 
 - [GAG, C, T, C]
 - [GA, G, C, TC]
 - [GA, G, C, T, C]
 - [G, A, G, C, T, C]
 - [G, AGC, TC]
Possible Outputs: [GAGCTC, TCGAGC]

Input: 
 - [AG, A, C, A, T, G]
 - [AG, A, C, A, T, G]
 - [AGAC, A, TG]
 - [AGA, CA, T, G]
 - [A, G, AC, A, T, G]
 - [A, G, A, C, ATG]
Possible Outputs: [AGACATG]

Input: 
 - [C, A, A, C, T]
 - [CA, A, C, T]
 - [CA, A, C, T]
 - [C, A, AC, T]
 - [C, A, A, C, T]
 - [C, AA, C, T]
Possible Outputs: [CAACT, TCAAC]

Input: 
 - [CA, G, C]
 - [CAG, C]
Possible Outputs: [CAGC, CCAG]

Input: 
 - [A, GT]
 - [A, G, T]
 - [AG, T]
Possible Outputs: [AGT]
```

There is a set of 100 random test cases [here](https://gist.github.com/SocraticPhoenix/167f4f62d1513b69e70c0c27da8fd16f), or you can check out the [java program](https://tio.run/##nVdbb9s2FH7XrzjLHkIhtpKmHQbESYAsKLaguwRLgD0UfaBlOqYrUypJJc0K//bs8CJZEikjqx50Ib9z4/l4DrWmj3RaVkysF59fXvimKqWGNQ5mteZFdiUlff6dKz1LgrnfqFrdsdjMjWaS6lJGpkZ0/U3FotxEJuIGlJaMbrLrsihYjobULEmqel7wHPKCKgV/UC7gW5IAXn5Caarx8VjyBWxwmtxpycXDx09A5YNKEQ3@WpYSCBcaOFzAyQwf5/DmxLwcHXVx5jLxnNubU3d5CZopjYIPTFxTxUg6CwU8FqpSKT4vGMKbV2LEBzLGF8X/7cIy8z3U/bTiqItoWbOhnyO@5mX1jFrzohRRy@YymEyyTfnIiH13pmEKbyJovnQgrt5vKv1M0pgn5ppjCj@H8ltghWIjMsHinXZXztiNeOS9svDG94sLu6BjvpnLp9EonY2CBgk8jSP3xrRnLaxssn9kmySRQDsUgUt4h3HC8fH9P@@vPpyBXsnyCcpawyMtaqbgiesVbErJcIoKeLeLigr1xKQKkzyd9r0djfDuWWm2ydBaVmHadCHIwY2oan0GB5Fc4dYj/SRT3PhnNhljyYqZQHIewJGVjljZvsrN22YV/qo1OqzOnEo/GlEbUTJA7Qy7N588RD9SzZoSla@otGVJIq2@HV4dTuDw3tyuze3Xw@0sUtcim7utQJ2Fi8AkUuACBHuCttqfX3Y9d8UZpHs4qBszqKRbpQomFPuCGAfOBPuqb4QmyMAjeDvbkVAxU7nx8aVmImdG8AFZuJRo4e3051ap8/KXmhcLJsHpNvZ7411n2@K9dsV7jcXbeYXvYf3G8YxW2P8WBNf748BtHMqcZ@mnjo1tEHQY8U8jEf8I5RKlDKHCaGOdB7WPd552m3CW2zRizm/tOzGR6dIBSDrx/g0IeXzseygvhcrUql4usZA6bSMiSJeMLhYeFF8VyXQthYHOejwPGdsEsPPbjbTMmPTpF3A5WIE9RB5NVmPMJ9s2t1OTwNORBDpr35U3CxOL1zhxbL09wj5rbv00OA9sJlpBVc@Vy/fJxNhIB6lrd9sFRGSMwCwJSxW2lB9a@Ghbj/gT1eap4eCvZUfb4iPlq7Gmxqmxa9J7yBG0ngI/4Cyu35YmtsOuSy6Yyal7uWVyU5s4cFcRo2d4oOt06b0HpRaF63pVFMSpT1/ZfJtzeOsmx4HuIZJ7AIl0M3@YNJBsRdWfyNLxw5zhiPMty0uh8XitnKRwYvsOWhbnz5fp9x6CxotQE2zLtQjZwlT2MtijhdstPTY0lroyDcz/q5A029DKcgGmjlu7GckWdc7IwcEECJ3APDUQint@nqa4nrZAk93PjinrzKzqnu1jIurvk@r/RBSK704J/r@vv3t62oNdNmlsTIyejtirGoX9ZRt3v5Jsyb9OIBbTJB5JN1RTj01L8BLBjxVfAhHmh@FkSOK2E1oHutUutiFjPSLeIcICZg3k7Y9aYLDNggO6KuzjeUCq8DQCjq3XzkZDilCugTZ7lncPgVE@eLdaFuRDGuw5G8cOyOf3l857fDpvmy9ba4d9AMfF/tovmvo6qNWenqIl5zZ5efkP) that generated them.

Comment: Too much intro, IMHO.

Comment: @Adám that was fast! I'll look into cutting down at that! Got to go do a thing now though, so it may be a while....

Comment: *any other unique characters* or numbers?

Comment: @Adám hmm... unique `values` i guess... I'll update it now

Answer (score 1):

## Minimize my cube

**Introduction**

[image: Using my 6x6 as cubes of smaller size]

I have a rubiks cube. It has 6 layers and is great fun to solve. But it takes quite some time, and sometimes I wish I could just solve a cube of smaller size. But theres hope, because *every cube with even number of layers can emulate every cube with less layers* by only moving certain layers at the same time. Now I need your help to provide the numbers.

**Let's get mathematical**

Consider this definiton: For every even integer *n* and a positive integer *i <= n* there exists a sequence of *i* positive integers, so that

```
x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_i = n
x_1 = x_i
x_2 = x_(i-1)
x_3 = x_(i-2)
...
```

(See test cases for a clearer example). Then such a sequence tells me exactly which layers to combine.

**The challenge**

For an input *n* write a program that outputs one of the existing sequences for every positive integer *i < n*.

**Test cases**

For *n = 6*:

```
[6]
[3, 3]
[2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

For *n = 4*:

```
[4]
[2, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Scoring and Rules**

Lowest number of bytes wins. Standard Loopholes apply.

**Sandbox quesions**

- Formatting?
- Can I make the definition clearer?
- Should I put more restrictions?
- Where is my english broken beyond repair?

Comment: Tell me if I'm understanding it wrong, but could we output, for the fourth line when n=6 : `[2, 1, 1, 2]`? or even `[2, 1, 2, 1]`? or even any permutation of `[1, 1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Another thing (that's why separate comment) : you don't explicitly require an input format. So here, could I for example output a string containing : `4\n22\n121\n1111\n` (with \n=newline)? Am I allowed to have this trailing newline? Are the commas mandatory? etc.

Comment: About my first comment : if you want, you can even ask for outputting *every* or *any* permutation, or a symmetric permutation, or an increasing-ordered one.

Comment: @V.Courtois: I meant it to be symmetric, like [2,1,1,2] and [1, 2, 2, 1] are both symmetric, but [2, 1, 2, 1] is not. Alas, need to better the explanation, I guess.

Comment: you do need, it's a fact :) And what about saying what *output* format you want (sorry for the *input* mistake in 2nd comment) ?

Answer (score 1):

## KOTH: Thirty-One [king-of-the-kill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-kill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

## Challenge

Built a bot that plays Thirty-One against other bots!

## Game Rules

Thirty-one is a card game using the standard 52-card deck (the French deck). The objective in each round is to have a hand better than at least one of your opponents'.

At the beginning of the game, each player has a set number of "lives" - for this challenge, each player will get 3 lives. Once you run out of lives, you have lost the game. No matter how many players there are, there is exactly one winner per game.

The player to go first in the first round is chosen arbitrarily. After that, the player to go first rotates clockwise around the "table". The players' order does not change between rounds (except for when players get knocked out).

At the beginning of each round, each player is dealt 3 cards. On each player's turn, they have the option to:

1. Draw a card from the deck and discard a card
2. Draw the last card that was discarded and discard a card
3. Knock if no other player has knocked yet

#### Knocking

If a player knocks, each other player gets one more turn. Then, the players compare hands. Whoever has the lowest score loses a life, and the round ends.

#### Scoring

Each player's score is calculated by adding the face values of all their same-suit cards and taking the best score. Two cards of different suits don't contribute to the same score.

The face values for each card are:

```
Ace: 11
King, Queen, Jack: 10
2-10: their value
```

For example, consider you hold the cards:

```
Ace of Spades
Four of Spades
Two of Spades
```

Your score would be `11 + 4 + 2 = 17`.

If you hold the cards:

```
Queen of Diamonds
Four of Clubs
Nine of Clubs
```

Your possible scores are `10` and `4 + 9 = 13`, so your score is `13`, the best of the two.

Finally, if you have:

```
Six of Hearts
Six of Spades
Three of Diamonds
```

Your possible scores are `6`, `6`, and `3`, so your score is `6`, the best of the three.

The highest possible score you can reach is 31, by holding the Ace and two 10-point cards of the same suit.

#### Special Cases

- If the player who would go first knocks immediately on their first turn, the other players *don't* get a turn - they compare hands right away
- If a player reaches a score of 31, they should knock immediately and *everyone* else loses a life
- If the deck runs out of cards, the round ends and all players compare hands

## Input/Output

Your bot will be a subclass of the base class I provide. You need not implement every method, but there will be a minimal amount of functionality required in order to make the turns go forward.

## Scoring

I will create a tournament-style bracket that will determine the winning bot. Your bot is allowed keep track of all the information available to it, including between games. The details of the bracket will depend on the number of bots written.

---

## Meta

- I could use some input on writing the controller and base class. What has worked well in the past? What hasn't worked that I should avoid?
- Are the rules for the game clear enough? I adapted them from my own knowledge of the game and [this website](http://www.bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/thirty-one/).
- Obviously this isn't ready for posting yet since I haven't written the base class, but is there anything else unclear or missing?
- Is there anything I can do to make this more fun or more challenging?

Comment: 1. The key thing for the controller is to maintain a persistent connection, because if you have to keep forking processes that becomes a bottleneck. 2. There are a couple of minor points to clarify. "*Whoever has the lowest score loses a life*": presumably in case of ties everyone with the lowest score loses one. "*standard 52-card deck*": the French deck, to distinguish it from other standards. Although on the basis of KISS I'd use a deck of four suits and card values 0 to 9 (with three 8s per suit).

Comment: "*Draw a card from the deck and discard a card*" is presumably followed by shuffling all but the discarded card if the draw deck runs out. "*I will run 100 games using everyone's bots*" will break badly if there are 17 bots.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you so much for the feedback! 1. Thank you for the advice, I didn't plan on making the program multi-processed, I planned on having the controller simply keep a list of the bots and passing control to each one in turn. 2. Yes the tying rule is correct, I'll add that in. Although that would be a good way to simplify the deck I think I'll keep it 2-11 with four 10s per suit, because I don't want to change the name of the game. 3. Yes, all but the top card would be shuffled back in, I'll add that as well. 4. Why would that break badly? Just because of computation time?

Comment: 3 cards each times 17 players leaves 1 card in the deck.

Comment: Ah, good point...if there are that many participants, I'll have to break it into multiple smaller games and set up a tournament bracket

Comment: I've changed my mind on one thing - the round ends when the deck runs out of cards. Each game will consist of 4 players, and I'll release more information about the gameplay once I see how many bots are written

Answer (score 1):

### How good is my mahjong hand?

Your goal is to calculate the ***shanten*** (minimal number of tiles needed for your hand to be a "waiting hand") of a [Riichi mahjong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Mahjong) hand.

**What is Japanese Mahjong (or Riichi)**

The goal of the game is to build a 14 tiles *valid* hand. Your hand is 13 tiles long, and each turn, you draw a 14th. If it doesn't make you win, you discard a tile.
The tiles are grouped by **colors** : *man*, numbers, let's call them `m`; *pin*, circles, `p`; *sou*, bamboos, `s`; and honor tiles, `z`.

For `p`,`m`, and `s` : tiles are numbered **from 1 to 9**, with **4 examples each** (`1m 1m 1m 1m 2m 2m 2m 2m 3m 3m 3m 3m... 9m 9m 9m 9m`).
`z` contains winds : *ton* for east, `e`; *nan* for south, `s`; *sha* or *xia* for west, `w`; and *pei* for north, `n`.
`z` contains dragons too : *chun* for red, `r`; *haku* for white, `h`; and *hatsu* for green, `g`.
**Same rule**, 4 examples each.
Honor tiles **cannot be sequenced in a *chii***, they can only combine with themselves, by **matching for a pair** or **for a *pon***. Don't worry, I will define terms *pon* and *chii* in the next part.

So a random hand can look like `1s 1s 1s 2s 2s 2s 3s 9p 9p 4m ez ez nz`.

**What is a "waiting hand"**

What is called a *tenpai* hand, or hand that is one tile left before winning, is a hand respecting a winning shape. In general, a winning hand is composed of 4 sets of 3 sequenced (*chii*, like `1s 2s 3s`) or matching (*pon*, like `1s 1s 1s`) tiles, plus a pair (like `1p 1p`). An example of a winning hand (14 tiles) can be : `1s 2s 3s 4s 5s 6s 6s 7s 8s 3p 3p 3p ez ez`
So a "waiting hand" can be : `1s 2s 3s 4s 5s 6s 6s 7s 8s 3p 3p 3p ez` where you need only `ez`to win.

**The goal**

To output a positive integer (between 0 and 7, inclusive) representing the *shanten* as defined above.
For instance, a hand like `1s 1s 1s 2s 2s 2s 3s 9p 9p 4m ez ez nz` is 2 *shanten*, because :
- you have a set of three `1s` (a *pon*)
- you have a *pon* of `2s`
- you have a pair of `9p` (your pair)
- you have another pair of `ez` (that needs a third one to become a *pon*)
- you have 3 "isolated" tiles, `3s`,`4m`,`nz`.

So drawing `ez`, and creating the *pon* of `ez`, makes you discard `nz` for example. Then let's imagine you draw `2s` : you discard `4m`, and you are now with a "waiting hand", with :
`1s 1s 1s 2s 2s 2s 2s 3s 9p 9p ez ez ez`, waiting on `1s` or `4s`.
You drew two "useful tiles" to come to this hand, so you were 2 *shanten*.

**@Sandbox** : Is it on-purpose to put **two** detailed examples? (**pro** : clarifies what you have to do / **con** : challenge's wall of text is even bigger)

**Another example**

Let's see your hand looks like `4p 5p 7p 1m 1m 1m 2s 4s 6s ez sz hz hz`.
- you have a *pon* of `1m`
- you have `4p` and `5p` sequenced, requiring `3p` or `6p` to be a *chii*
- you have `2s 4s 6s`, requiring `3s` or `5s` to create a *chii*
- you have a pair of `hz`
- you have 3 "isolated" tiles, `7p`, `ez` and `sz`.

So, as for the first example, we have 3 isolated tiles. But are we 2 *shanten*? No, because `2s 4s 6s` is not complete. So in fact, we have 4 useless tiles, the 4th being `2s` or `6s` depending on what we draw.
Proof : if we draw `3p`, `3s` and `hz`, our hand looks like that :
`3p 4p 5p 1m 1m 1m 2s 3s 4s sz hz hz hz`
and is waiting on the second `sz` to form the pair and win. We drew 3 useful tiles, so we were 3 *shanten*.

**Test cases**

```
3m 6m 9m 3p 5p 8p 1s 5s 8s ez sz nz gz -> 7 shanten
3m 6m 9m 3p 4p 5p 8p 1s 5s 8s ez sz nz -> 6 shanten
3m 6m 9m 3p 4p 5p 8p 1s 5s 8s ez nz nz -> 5 shanten
3m 6m 9m 3p 4p 5p 8p 8p 5s 8s ez nz nz -> 4 shanten
3m 5m 6m 9m 3p 4p 5p 8p 8p 5s 8s nz nz -> 4 shanten
3m 4m 5m 6m 3p 4p 5p 8p 8p 5s 8s nz nz -> 3 shanten
3m 4m 5m 6m 3p 4p 5p 8p 8p 5s 5s nz nz -> 2 shanten
3m 4m 5m 6m 7m 3p 4p 5p 8p 5s 5s nz nz -> 1 shanten
3m 4m 5m 6m 7m 3p 4p 5p 5s 5s nz nz nz -> 0 shanten
6s 7s 8s 1p 1p 1p 3p 4p 5p 6p 7p 7p 7p -> 0 shanten
3s 4s 5s 6s 7s 2p 4p 6p ez nz nz hz gz -> 3 shanten
3s 4s 5s 6s 7s 7s 1p 2p 4p 6p nz nz hz -> 2 shanten
3s 3s 4s 5s 6s 7s 7s 2p 4p sz sz nz nz -> 2 shanten
3s 3s 4s 5s 5s 6s 7s 7s 4p nz nz sz sz -> 2 shanten
3s 3s 3s 4s 5s 5s 7s 8s 2p 3p 4p 6p 6p -> 1 shanten
1m 1m 1m 2s 7s 7s 1p 3p 4p 9p sz hz cz -> 4 shanten
3m 6m 9m 3p 8p 1s 5s 8s ez sz nz gz cz -> 8 shanten
```

**Protip**

Calculating *shanten* can be complex, so [here is a link](http://arcturus.su/wiki/Shanten) that can help you doing so. You can refer to [this site](http://arcturus.su/wiki/Main_Page) if you need any other information on riichi mahjong. Good luck!

**Scoring and extra rules**

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins for its language.
[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

**NB** : If you know mahjong, or were curious and dug deeper into the rules, don't mind with specific shapes like [seven pairs](http://arcturus.su/wiki/Chiitoitsu) or [thirteen orphans](http://arcturus.su/wiki/Kokushi_musou).

**tags** : [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
**@Sandbox** : should I create some sort of [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) in a pastebin or something?
[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239028/how-do-i-calculate-the-shanten-number-in-mahjong)
[Related too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154960/algorithm-to-find-streets-and-same-kind-in-a-hand)
[Something that can help if you speak japanese](http://tenhou.net/2/) `<-` you can copypaste in the field the output from [this program](https://tio.run/##Xc9NCsIwFATgtTnFI6sGROiPioKLHsCVXiCmrz8S09BElJaePT5UEAMDA99qximpZegvV1QejrIzgE@PpnJQWjuxRYU11P1wRtP298TvT37oTCO@fZiCXw1otVRYap1w4EvOxR8hURqZGwmzMdIHYR6ZISsia8jWkbVkm8gU2ZaLMDNmaa3XJvld4ekNPskcbN9JLeQWCgs7C26EdgRFEwWbwws) :)
[Another protip](https://www.reddit.com/r/Mahjong/comments/5p20gg/how_do_you_quickly_calculate_the_number_of_shanten/?st=j5c9i5ar&sh=62c24e67)

**SANDBOX**

Feel free to comment and tell me if this is on-purpose in PPCG, if there is any way to improve the way I say things, if I'm unclear anywhere ...

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why (by commenting or suggesting edit) so I can improve. If you don't, then don't downvote, this makes just the post less visible for no reason.

Comment: Didn't downvote this, nor have I read through it yet. But that may be the reason it just appears to be a wall of text. Maybe try splitting it up into multiple posts or breaking the text down into easier read chunks. Or even take bits out that might not be needed.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder in fact I'd like to explain clearly what is mahjong (to put some context in the challenge). Though you're right, it **is** a wall of text, that's what it looks like to me too. And I can't really "split it" into multiple posts, because it is what the challenge will look like in the end. **TL;DR** I want to be as clear as possible since this challenge is gonna be hard.

Comment: I think you should be able to make it clearer by tidying the post up and formatting it more. The problem is a lot of people will open the question see all the text and move on without giving it a chance

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I do know about this. How do you think I can make it tidier without removing content?

Comment: To be honest I have no clue, if I knew more on the subject I'd be able to help more

Comment: @TheLethalCoder mmh okay. Japanese mahjong is a well documented topic (I already linked some docs in the post). So maybe I shouldn't define the rules myself and let a link do the job?

Comment: Well you'd want the important information in the post so it is self contained. Maybe the "fluff" can be trimmed down.

Answer (score 1):

## KotH: Atom Bomb Chess

(Draft. I'll flesh it out some more later. It will probably be implemented in JavaScript or maybe C++.)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

Atom Bomb Chess is a variant of chess played much the same as regular chess. The only differences are:

1. The game ends when one or both players have no pieces, or if 50 moves have been made without a piece being captured.
2. When a piece is captured, all pieces a king's move away are also "captured", and the piece doing the capturing is also "captured".

For example, let's look at a 4x4:

```
pbbr
....
....
RBBP
```

Where `r`/`R` is a rook, `b`/`B` is a bishop, and `p`/`P` is a pawn. Suppose `R` moves forward 3 spaces. Then, it captures the `p` and "explodes":

```
..br
....
....
.BBP
```

The idea of this KotH is to make a program that plays Atom Bomb Chess. I will have a few programs to test your submissions against.

Comment: This is a really cool idea! Obviously you'll need to flesh out the rules a bit more, but this is a great start. I would also suggest fixing the board size (you seem to suggest it can be played on any size board, but I think it would be easiest to set it as a constant ahead of time).

Comment: @musicman523 Yeah, it'd probably be played on an 8x8

Comment: you forgot that pawns are partially nuke proof

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Please elaborate ? I wasn't aware there was some standard rulebook.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where it is, but I remember that pawns, while still being eliminated if they are capturing, or are captured, will not get removed if they are adjacent to a capture. maybe use lichess?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I remember playing it when I was younger with no such restriction, perhaps there are multiple variants. Why suggest lichess? Does it have that mode?

Comment: Apart from pawns being nuke proof, the game ends as soon as you nuke the enemy king, if you play on lichess. There are [videos on YouTube](https://youtu.be/K5KNQLCsbuw) which include an explanation of the rules and basic "opening theory".

Answer (score 1):

## Who Won the Chess Game?

***Bear with me, this is incredibly bare-bones at the moment; I'll work on this over-time, just wanted to gauge interest on the over-all idea.***

---

Given an input list of moves `l`, output who won the chess game given that white always goes first, alternating moves from there. Using the following convention for naming the chess squares:

[image]

Where the pieces are:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

The first assumption you will make is that the list of moves passed is a VALID chess game, to completion. The following would be an example input:

```
[[A2,A4],[A7,A6],...]
```

The first two moves given would result in:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
P.......
........
.PPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

Which is white's first move, followed by black's move:

```
rnbqkbnr
.ppppppp
p.......
........
P.......
........
.PPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

Then, you would continue parsing moves until a king disappears. Whichever king is left should be declared the winner.

---

## Waiting to Gauge Interest Before Wasting Time on Full Testcase

Comment: [Related 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3229/42963), [Related 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3229/42963), [Possible Dupe 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3727/42963)

Answer (score 1):

### Nested list unpacking [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In Python 3.5+, the `*` operator can  [unpack a list within a list](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

```python
[1,*[2,3,4],5] == [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The unpacked elements are placed directly into the outer list without increasing the list depth. Note that this is different from the nested three-element list

```python
[1,[2,3,4],5]
```

Your goal is to simplify a nested list expression by resolving all instances of unpacking. So, the output will simply be a nested list without any `*`.

Specifically, the input will be an expression that consists of

- A non-empty list of expressions `[..]`
- An non-empty unpacked list of expressions `*[..]`.
- A digit 1 through 9

The outermost layer will always be a non-empty list. The output is such an expression without any unpacking.

**Input:** A string of characters `[],*123456789`

**Output:** Its unpacked analogue. This can be a string or list structure.

This challenge can be done in any language. Python and other languages with the same unpacking format may not use `eval` or `exec` or equivalents.

TODO: I/O details, test cases

Comment: This is similar to least Levenshtein distance to a balanced list (replace `*[` with `{` and then remove unbalanced `]`).

Answer (score 1):

### Title: Visualizing Euclid's Algorithm

### Problem

We wish to visualize Euclid's algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor of two numbers as a 2-dimensional tiling, such as this one:

[image: euclid]

This [interactive version](https://www.geogebra.org/m/JstAZYHG) may also be helpful in understanding the visualization.

### Input

Two positive integers `a` and `b`, where `a > b`.  You may take them in any order and in any convenient form: a list, two function args, etc.

### Output

An ascii version of the above visualization shown above.  This is best illustrated with a few examples:

#### input = 20, 8

```
.....................
.       .       .   .
.       .       .   .
.       .       .   .
.       .       .....
.       .       .   .
.       .       .   .
.       .       .   .
.....................
```

8 goes into 20 2 times, so we have two 8x8 squares, and remainder of 4 (20 - 8*2 = 4).  4 goes into 8 2 times with no remainder, so the remaining rectangle is broken into to 2 4x4 squares and we're done.

#### input = 5, 3

```
......
.  ...
.  . .
......
```

Note: There is an implied connection between any two *adjacent* dots, so that the above ascii should be interpreted as follows:

[image: connected nodes]

#### input = 7, 3

```
........
.  .  ..
.  .  ..
........
```

#### flexibility

You may choose whichever border characters are prettiest to you, or use combinations of different characters.

```
.....................   *********************   +-------+-------+---+
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.       .       .....   *       *       *****   |       |       +---+
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.       .       .   .   *       *       *   *   |       |       |   |
.....................   *********************   +-------+-------+---+
```

Rotations are also allowed: Any of the above may be rotated 90, -90, or 180 degrees.

### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard loophole rules, etc.

Comment: Nice challenge! But I would add a test cases like `8,5` and `21,13` where the recursion goes a bit deeper.

Comment: @BruceForte thanks.  unfortunately since posting it I found this, which I fear is too similar: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119714/visualize-the-euclidean-algorithm-again

Comment: Yeah you're right, didn't know these existed.

Answer (score 1):

> #### *NB: work in progress*

## Convert MADBACE to DECIMAL

MADBACE is a mixed Roman-hexdecimal system. Hexadecimal digits (0-F) take their normal positional values, while Roman numerals (IVXLCDM) have their normal values (1 5 10 50 100 500 1000). The main parts of the challenge is to determine when to subtract and when C and D are Roman versus hexadecimal.

#### Rules

1. `C` and `D` will be Roman if possible.
2. There can never be more than one subtractive symbol to the left of any symbol.
3. A subtractive symbol must be less than half the symbol it subtracts from

#### Examples

`CM` → `900`

`MC` → `1100`

`MD` → `1500`

`DM` → `792` 1000-13×16<sup>1</sup>

`LD` → `450`

`CD` → `400`

`XD` → `40`

`ID` → `49` 13×16<sup>0</sup>-1

`3C` → `52` 100-3×16<sup>1</sup>

`4C` → `76` 4×16<sup>1</sup>+12×16<sup>0</sup>

`MADBACE` → `701590` (10×16<sup>5</sup>-1000)+(11×16<sup>3</sup>-500)+10×16<sup>2</sup>+100+14×16<sup>0</sup>

`DECIMAL` → `233571513` 13×16<sup>6</sup>+14×16<sup>5</sup>+12×16<sup>4</sup>+(1000-1)+10×16<sup>1</sup>+50

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [roman-numerals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-numerals) [hexadecimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexadecimal)

Comment: Maybe make explicit mention that a smaller symbol to the left of a larger symbol is always subtracted if both are Roman. And if one is Roman? What if neither are? Actually if neither are then the position based value ensures the symbol to the left is always larger.

Comment: If only a single symbol can be to the left for subtraction, how are ambiguous cases like IXL resolved?

Comment: Are all possible inputs from the symbol alphabet to be dealt with, or just some subset? I mean, does the spec resolve all ambiguities or will the challenge specify "only valid inputs will be used"?

Answer (score 1):

**Calculate the maximum possible number of "living" cells on a given grid size for Conway's Game Of Life.**

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

[Conway's Game Of Life](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

**Game Rules:**

1. Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by underpopulation.
2. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
3. Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
4. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

---

**Challenge:** 
For a given grid size (ex 5x5) is it possible to calculate the maximum potential living cells after at least 5 generations with any given starting pattern?

```
 O O X O O
 O O X O O
 X X X X X
 O O X O O
 O O X O O
```

In the above example, there are 16 living cells.  I am not proposing that this is the maximum, just providing a starting point.

The reason for the 5th generation requirement is because the first generation could technically be 25 (100%) I suppose.

Comment: To me, this is a very interesting challenge because brute-forcing it would be difficult (5x5 board has 2^25=32 million possibilities for starting). That being said, this should be marked as [tag:code-golf] or [tag:fastest-code] as a winning criterion (read the [tag:code-challenge] description). Also, the rules should specify that all eight surrounding cell are included in the count. Is the board toroidal (i.e. edge wrapping) or flat? Are there any limits on the grid size? Importantly, this needs test cases to be a good challenge. If a 5x5 example is too big, do a 3x3 example.

Answer (score 1):

## Can you compete with a  supercomputer?

The challenge is to write super fast code for computing the [permanent of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of complex numbers.

In [a paper from 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05836) a team of coders managed to compute the permanent of a 40 by 40 complex matrix on 8192 nodes of what was at the time the world's fastest computer in  about 14 seconds.  Your challenge is to see how close you can get to this on my desktop.

The permanent of an `n`-by-`n` matrix `A` = (`a`<sub>`i,j`</sub>) is defined as

[image]

Here `S_n` represents the set of all permutations of `[1, n]`.

As an example (from the wiki):

[image]

In this question matrices are all square.

### Examples (these need updating to have complex entries)

Input:

```
[[ 1 -1 -1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1  1]
 [-1  1 -1  1]
 [ 1 -1 -1  1]]
```

Permanent:

```
-4
```

Input:

```
[[-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1]]
```

Permanent:

```
0
```

Input:

```
[[ 1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1]
 [ 1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1]
 [-1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1]]
```

Permanent:

```
192
```

Input:

```
[[1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1],
 [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
 [-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
 [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
 [1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1],
 [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1],
 [-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
 [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1],
 [1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1],
 [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]]
```

Permanent:

```
1021509632
```

### Add the 40 by 40 matrix here

### The task

You should write code that, given an `n` by `n` complex  matrix, outputs its permanent.

To make testing simpler, I will provide a single `40` by `40` complex matrix which you can hardcode into your code in any format of your choosing. Clearly, you are not allowed to precompute the answer however!

### Scores and ties

I will test your code on the sample `40` by `40` complex matrix.  Your score is your time in seconds divided by 14.

If two people are within 1 second of each other then the winner is the one posted first.

### Languages and libraries

You can use any available language and libraries you like but no pre-existing function to compute the permanent. I will run your code under OS X so please give full instructions for how to compile and run it.

### Reference implementations

There is already a [codegolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96825/codegolf-the-permanent) question with lots of code in different languages for computing the permanent for small matrices.  There was also a [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97060/calculate-the-permanent-as-quickly-as-possible) on computing the permanent of matrices with only +-1 entries.  The coding issues when you have complex entries and want things to run fast and multi-core are quite different however.

### My Machine

The timings will be run on my Mac desktop. The CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz`.

Comment: Remember `#asdfjkl;` and `##asdfjkl;`, not `**asdfjkl;**`, for headings.

Comment: Why divide the score by 14? I know it ties in with the story, but surely it primarily adds to confusion. Also, will all the input matrices only contain `+/-1`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman No the matrices will have complex entries.  I need to change the examples. Dividing by 14 was just for fun to compare with the supercomputer. I can remove that if you think it's better.

Answer (score 1):

## Survival Island

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

> **Work in Progress, mainly trying to get the idea out and see if anyone is interested. Also make sure it hasn't been done already. Ideas taken from The Hunger Game and Player Unknown Battleground**

## The Board

The game will be played on a square 2-dimensional array with the size of x + ny where n is the number of players, and x and y are to be determined. No wrap

## Objects

All objects can be destroyed while on the map, hence their hp. Once they are picked up, they cannot be destroyed unless the player dies.

1.Wall: Denoted by the character 'W'

```
HP: 10
Object Type: Wall
```

2.Reinforced Wall: Denoted by the character 'R'. When a wall is upgraded to reinforced wall by the player, 10 hp is added to the remaining hp on the wall.

```
HP: 20
Object Type: Wall
```

3.Crossbow: Denoted by the character 'C'. Allow the player to have ranged attack with a distance of 2. The damage dealt will be the player's damage minus 1.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 1
Upgrade #1: damage + 1
Upgrade #2: attacking distance + 1, damage + 1
Object Type: Item(Equipment)
```

4.Dagger: Denoted by the character 'D'. If the player is attacking with a distance of 1, it does 1 extra damage.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 1
Upgrade #1: damage + 1
Upgrade #2: damage + 2
Object Type: Item(Equipment)
```

5.Binocular: Denoted by the character 'B'. Increase the player's line of sight by 1.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 1
Upgrade #1: line of sight + 1
Upgrade #2: line of sight + 1
Object Type: Item(Equipment)
```

6.Shield: Denoted by the character 'S'. Increases the player's block by 1

```
HP: 2
Weight: 1
Upgrade #1: nothing
Upgrade #2: block + 1
Object Type: Item(Equipment)
```

7.Armor: Denoted by the character 'A'. negates 1 damage from any incoming damage to the player.

```
HP: 2
Weight: 2
Upgrade #1: nothing
Upgrade #2: incoming damage - 1
Object Type: Item(Equipment)
```

8.MedicKit: Denoted by the character 'M'. When used, heal the player's health by 5.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 0.5
Upgrade #1: hp restored + 3
Upgrade #2: hp restored + 5
Object Type: Item(Consumable)
```

9.EnergyDrink: Denoted by the character 'E'. When used, increase STR, AGI, and VIT by 1 for 5 turns. (If the player has already drank an energy drink, it will override previous effect).

```
HP: 1
Weight: 0.5
Upgrade #1: buff duration + 3 turns
Upgrade #2: all attribute + 1
Object Type: Item(Consumable)
```

10.PoisonedEnergyDrink: Denoted by the character 'E'. When used, decrease STR, AGI, and VIT by 1 for 3 turns.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 0.5
Upgrade #1: buff duration + 2 turns
Upgrade #2: all attribute - 1
Object Type: Item(Consumable)
```

11.UpgradeKit: Denoted by the character "U". Used to upgrades other items. All item can be upgraded twice. 1 upgrade kit is used to upgrade an item once.

```
HP: 1
Weight: 1
Upgrade #1: nothing
Upgrade #2: nothing
Object Type: Item(Special)
```

12.Player - Denoted by the character 'P'. This is the actual player on the board. See next section for more details.

```
HP: determined by the player
Object Type: Player
```

E.g. In the following map, the player have a line of sight of 1.

```
-------------
|   | A |   | 
-------------
| R | P |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
```

In particular. There's a reinforced wall on the left, and a piece of armor on the top. the player is at the center. This can be represented as [{0,1,A},{1,0,R},{1,1,P}]

## The player

Each player have the following 3 attributes:

- STR: affects damage and carrying capacity of the player. +1 damage for each 2 STR and +1 capacity for each 1 STR
- AGI: affects player's movement range and line of sight. +1 movement for each 5 AGI, and +1 line of sight for each 3 AGI
- VIT: affects player's health and block. +3 health for each 1 VIT, and +1 block for each 3 VIT

You are free to assign 0 to 10 attribute points to the above 3 attributes when creating your character. Any character with more than 10 attributes assigned at the start of the game is disqualified.

Each player will start off with the following stats (without attribute bonus):

- health: 20
- damage: 1
- carrying capacity: 3
- movement: 1
- line of sight : 2
- block: 0

## Game play

Each turn, the player will perform a move and an action.

#### Movement phase

Movement can either be '^' for up, 'v' for down, '<' for left, '>' right or '.' for stay.

If you can move 2 or more tiles, you can provide all movements in the order you want them to executed (e.g. "^>" will move up then right, and ">^" will move right then up).

If the first movement fails(due to object being there), the subsequent movements are dropped.

The movement phase is performed by every player performing their first movement, then every player performing their second movement if available, etc.

If 2 or more players attempt to move to the same square, then the player with the highest agility wins. If they have the same agility, then it's determined by a dice roll.

#### Action phase

Each player can perform the following actions during the action phase

1. Attack  : Denoted by "A  ". Performs an attack to the coordinate x,y If the coordinate is out of reach, then do nothing. x and y should be relevant to the player, e.g. 0,-1 is attacking down adjacent to the player.
2. Block: Denote by "B". Performs an block on each incoming attacks with the chance of block/10. If the block succeeds, negate all damage from that attack.
3. Pickup : Denoted by "P ". Tries to pick up an object at that direction adjacent to the player. If the tile is empty, or if picking up the item exceeds your carrying capacity, then do nothing.
4. Drop  : Denoted by "D  ". Tries to drop an item at that direction adjacent to the player. If the tile is already occupied, or the item does not exist. then do nothing.
5. Build Wall : Denoted by "W ". Tries to build a wall at that direction adjacent to the player. If the tile is already occupied, then do nothing.
6. Reinforce wall : Denoted by "R ". Tries to upgrade a wall at that direction adjacent to the player. If the tile is not a wall or player do not have UpgradeKit, then do nothing.
7. Consume : Denoted by "C ". Consumes an item in your inventory. If the item does not exist, then do nothing.
8. Upgrade : Denoted by "U ". Upgrades an item in your inventory. If the item does not exist, or if you have no UpgradeKit, or if the item already maxed out upgrades. Then do nothing
9. Equip : Denoted by "E ". Equips an item. If the item does not exist, then it does nothing, If you have already equipped an item. then put that item in the inventory.
10. Sleep: Denoted by "S". Increase health by 3. increases all incoming damage by 1. increase movement, damage, and block next turn by 1. Last one turn.
11. Gaze into the sky: Denoted by "G". Looks up into the sky and ponder about life (Do nothing).

If 2 players try to perform an action at the same tile, It is first determined by the order of actions. If the players uses the same action, then the highest agility player wins. if they have the same agility, then it's determined by a dice roll who should succeed.

Order of actions that is Sleep > Block > Consume > Equip > Upgrade > Gaze > Reinforce Wall > Pickup > Drop > Build Wall > Attack

example: Given an empty tile x. if player a performs pickup at tile x, player b performs drop on tile x, player c performs build on tile x, and player d performs attack on tile x. Then player a does nothing, player b drops an item on tile x. player c does nothing, and player d attacks that item

## Input/Output

Each round, the following is output to each player for movement and again for action:
round #, phase, player inventory, player equipment, player buffs, player capacity, attack, block, movement, los, player hp, player line of sight, possibly more?

e.g.
14,M,AEEMM,B,P2E3,6,5,1,1,3,19,[{0,1,A},{1,0,R},{1,1,P}]

indicates:

- round 14
- currently it's movement phase.
- player is carrying Armor, 2 * Poisoned? Energy Drink, 2 * Medic Kit
- player is equipping Binocular
- player current have a buff of poisoned energy drink with 2 turns remaining, and energy drink with 3 turns remaining
- player has a maximum of 6 carrying capacity
- player has an attack of 5
- player has a block of 1
- player has a movement of 1
- player has a line of sight of 3
- player has a hp of 19
- player sees the map as shown before

Each round, 2 inputs will be read from the players

#### Movement phase

use '^','<','v','>' to indicate movement direction and '.' for stay, if you can move 3 times, output 3 characters.

e.g.
"<.<" indicates you move left, wait then left again

#### Action phase

output one of the actions listed in game play

e.g.
- "E 1" equips the 1st item in your inventory if possible
- "A 1 2" attacks 1 tile to the right and 2 tile above you if possible.

## Determine winner

a game ends if only 1 bot is alive or it is played to 1000 turns.

each each live bot gets 1/<# of bots alive> points

x games will be played and the points will be totaled to determine the winner.

## Additional Information

- Damage is calculated by attack - armor defense. If the defending player used Block, then there is block/10 chance to completely negate all damage.
- All distance are Manhattan distance
- More items spawn near the center than border (if I can find a way to do this efficiently)
- Player can pick roughly where they spawn such as near border or near center (if I can find a way to do this efficiently)

## Questions/To-Do list

- Figure out what's a good map size
- Too many/little actions/objects?
- Balance items and stats?
- Is the game clear enough?
- Is output and input sufficient for the gameplay?
- Any suggestions or comments?
- Format question so it looks nicer. Make important information stand out. Fix grammer
- Catchy title?
- Figure out how many games to play to get winner
- Make it shorter? wall of text is not fun D:
- Figure out how many of each object to spawn
- When player die, randomly drop an item, drop equipped item, drop nothing?
- Find time to write the controller
- Figure out how to use the site

Answer (score 1):

## Proposed Question

### Triskaidekaphobic Primes

It is known that a certain number, which lies between 12 and 14, brings bad luck. The Church of Triskaidekaphobia (CoTDP) asserts that the key to salvation is avoiding this number in all situations, such as numbering [floors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_floor), [license plates](http://www.independent.ie/irish-news/2013-number-plates-to-be-changed-to-avoid-unlucky-13-26890349.html), [space shuttle missions](http://www.spacepatches.nl/sts_mis/sts13.html) and more.

The IT department of CoTDP is looking for talented developers. Candidates must prove their ability to program in accordance with Triskaidekaphobic dogma. Can you get this prestigious job?

### Your Mission

Write a program that prints all prime numbers below 1000, excluding the unlucky one. the program must obey the CoTDP programming rules.

### Rules

1. Numbers whose absolute value is greater than 12 and smaller than 14 are considered unlucky and must be avoided.
2. Unlucky numbers must not be used in the program:

   - Must not appear in the program, in any representation/base.
   - Must not be the value of an expression or calculation (e.g. `5 + 8`).
   - Must not be an intermediate value in an expression (e.g. `5 + 8 + 3`, `35 % 22 == 0`).
   - Must not be stored in a variable, register, memory etc (e.g. `for i in xrange(20):`).
   - Must not be passed to a function or returned from one.
   - The above applies to any complex type which contains an unlucky number (e.g. `range(20)` in Python 2).
   - The above applies to all expressions, not just constant expressions (e.g. `x+1` is invalid if `x` happens to be 12).
3. No calculation, or intermediate value of a calculation, may yield an unlucky number. For example,  and `for i in xrange(20):` are forbidden.
4. Output lines bust be separated by line-feed only (no carriage return).
5. You must find primes using basic mathematical operations. If your language provides tools to find primes or test primality, you must not use them.
6. [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/3544) apply.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), the shortest solution (in bytes) wins.

## Questions for Meta

- Do the limitations make sense for all sorts of languages? I think they cover languages such as C/Python/Java that use expressions, and also languages such as BrainFuck that manipulate memory (I think it's obvious that you must not write 13 in a memory cell).
- Is there a trivial solution that makes it uninteresting?
- Would it be better as a popularity contest?
- Or maybe, accept the shortest, but give a bounty for the most interesting/creative answer?
- Can the expression "Church of Triskaidekaphobia" be considered offensive to followers of some churches?

Comment: Should we treat numbers such as `39` (`13 * 3`) as prime, or not prime for the sake of this calculation? If `13` is not a prime, then `39` is, but it's up to you. (I did something kind of similar to this [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117181/palindromic-primes-without-11))

Comment: @StepHen, IMO, an unlucky divisor is still a divisor. I think asking for "primes below 1000, excluding the unlucky one" makes it clear. Your interpretation might make it more challenging, but I'm not sure how it would work - 39 is a multiple of 3 (though you shouldn't actually do this division), so how can it be prime? Maybe 169.

Comment: Related: we are not allowed to store `13`, right?

Comment: @StepHen, I'm not sure what you mean by "store". My intention is that 13 won't be used in any way. I write that it can't be used in the program and can't be derived by calculation, so how can it be stored?

Comment: Well you could store it with `x = ord("\r")`, although if you can't use it there's not much point.

Comment: `ord("\r")` is an expression that yields 13, and is therefore invalid. But it's worth clarifying.

Comment: Your post (as it stands) says no calculation, not no expression.

Comment: `Numbers whose absolute value is greater than 12 and smaller than 14 are considered unlucky and must be avoided.` is 12.5 allowed?

Answer (score 1):

## Encrypt/Decrypt a Decimal in Binary

Given either a positive integer `a` or two positive integers `b` and `c`, either encrypt or decrypt the integer(s).

---

## Encryption

Given `a=33344492`, for example:

1. Split `a` into consecutive runs: `[333,444,9,2]`.
2. Replace all runs with alternating 1's and 0's starting with 1: `[111,000,1,0]`.
3. Place back into binary: `11100010`
4. Convert to decimal: `226`
5. Calculate decryption key: `3492`

   - This key is the unique characters from each distinct run.
6. Return `[226, 3492]` as the answer, these represent `[b, c]` respectively.

## Decryption

Given `b=226` and `c=3492`:

1. Convert `b` into binary: `11100010`
2. Use `c` to "replace" in each character.

   - `11100010 -> 33300010 -> 33344410 -> 33344490 -> 33344492`
3. Print the single integer answer, `a=33344492`.

---

## More Examples (For Decryption, Reverse Examples)

```
12349149
[170,12349149]

99922211100
[1820,9210]

2
[1,2]

9
[1,9]

10
[2,10]

100
[4,10]

0
[1,0]

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
[10141204801825835211973625643007,1]

111222333444555666777888999000
[954437176,1234567890]

10101010101010
[10922, 10101010101010]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be one or two challenges myself.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder based on the number of inputs, you perform a different function. It's one challenge, though it'd be equally viable as two; but it's not interesting enough for 2 challenges.

Comment: Yeah that's why I wasn't sure. Just commenting in case you hadn't thought of splitting it up.

Comment: The decryption stage might be clearer if you use a number that doesn't contain `0`s and `1`s.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder fixed.

Comment: For your first test case you show a walkthrough. I'd either move it to an actual walkthrough place or remove the steps.

Comment: The first time you talk about the decryption key you say it's `1092`. Shouldn't it be `3492`?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo it used to be 11100092 but I changed it to 33344492, nice catch; missed that.

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a Spiral Matrix

- Related: [Print NxN spiral of ascending numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/769/print-nxn-spiral-of-ascending-numbers) - This challenge is meant to replace that old challenge by covering all spiral matrices.

Given `N`, generate one out of all the spiral matrices with dimensions `N x N` using the values `[0, 1, ..., n-1]`.

For example, if `N = 5`, there are 16 ways to generate a spiral matrix

```
 0  1  2  3  4    12 13 14 15  0     8  9 10 11 12     4  5  6  7  8
15 16 17 18  5    11 22 23 16  1     7 20 21 22 13     3 18 19 20  9
14 23 24 19  6    10 21 24 17  2     6 19 24 23 14     2 17 24 21 10
13 22 21 20  7     9 20 19 18  3     5 18 17 16 15     1 16 23 22 11
12 11 10  9  8     8  7  6  5  4     4  3  2  1  0     0 15 14 13 12

 0 15 14 13 12     4  3  2  1  0     8  7  6  5  4    12 11 10  9  8
 1 16 23 22 11     5 18 17 16 15     9 20 19 18  3    13 22 21 20  7
 2 17 24 21 10     6 19 24 23 14    10 21 24 17  2    14 23 24 19  6
 3 18 19 20  9     7 20 21 22 13    11 22 23 16  1    15 16 17 18  5
 4  5  6  7  8     8  9 10 11 12    12 13 14 15  0     0  1  2  3  4

24 23 22 21 20    12 11 10  9 24    16 15 14 13 12    20 19 18 17 16
 9  8  7  6 19    13  2  1  8 23    17  4  3  2 11    21  6  5  4 15
10  1  0  5 18    14  3  0  7 22    18  5  0  1 10    22  7  0  3 14
11  2  3  4 17    15  4  5  6 21    19  6  7  8  9    23  8  1  2 13
12 13 14 15 16    16 17 18 19 20    20 21 22 23 24    24  9 10 11 12

24  9 10 11 12    20 21 22 23 24    16 17 18 19 20    12 13 14 15 16
23  8  1  2 13    19  6  7  8  9    15  4  5  6 21    11  2  3  4 17
22  7  0  3 14    18  5  0  1 10    14  3  0  7 22    10  1  0  5 18
21  6  5  4 15    17  4  3  2 11    13  2  1  8 23     9  8  7  6 19
20 19 18 17 16    16 15 14 13 12    12 11 10  9 24    24 23 22 21 20
```

You are allowed to use a parameter `P` to determine which out of the 16 spiral matrices you will generate.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so make your code as short as possible.
- `N >= 1`
- The parameter `P` should be a value such as a number, character, or any other reasonably simple value.
- You may output the spiral matrix as a 2d array of numbers or characters, a formatted string, or any other easily understandable format.

Comment: Alternatively, the challenge might be to ignore `P` and just generate all 16 spiral matrices.

Comment: Also [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125966/36398)

Answer (score 1):

## Interpret a Maximal Number of Brainf*** Variants

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

[A while ago in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39124258#39124258), I had an idea:

[image]

It was prompty shot down as impossible. Because of that, I'm making it a challenge!

## Valid Languages

The only valid brainfuck variants you can use are the languages appearing on [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703051845/http://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Brainfuck_derivatives) and [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703100409/http://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Brainfuck_equivalents) (along with regular brainfuck, of course). Those two links are July 3rd, 2017 captures of the esolangs.org pages for brainfuck derivatives and brainfuck equivalents.

## The Task

Your task is to create **one** program that, when fed code from any variant of brainfuck you say you can interpret, along with input for that program, will execute that code according to the spec of that variant. *You cannot tell the interpreter beforehand what variant it is supposed to interpret.*

There is one very important note: in brainfuck, for example, all characters not used are ignored as comments. Any program that is entered will not contain comments. **All input will *only* contain characters that are not ignored by the spec**.

Knowing this, if two variants of brainfuck overlap enough that you cannot differentiate between two valid, however short, programs in them, and if each language wants a different result, you can only include one of those languages.

## Scoring

The most important part of this challenge is maximizing the number of variants you can support. However, you also don't want to make it *too* long. Therefore, the following is your score:

> (variantsSupported * 300) - interpreterBytes

*Highest score wins.*

Comment: yeah the problem is that ignored characters are not well defined. that is, any string of characters, excluding [ and ] (they might be misbalanced) is a valid bf program. that's a part of the spec pretty much

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I'm (trying) to remove that from the spec - if part of the spec is that some chars are no-ops, your interpreter does not have to handle them

Answer (score 1):

## Is this 2048 board valid?

Some 2048 boards are impossible to get into.  For example,

```
2 _ _ 2
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
2 _ _ 2
```

will never occur in a 2048 game.  Additionally, these are all impossible:

```
8 _ _ 8    8 _ _ _    2 2 2 2
_ _ _ _    _ 8 _ _    2 2 _ _
_ _ _ _    _ _ _ _    _ _ _ _
8 _ _ _    _ _ _ _    _ _ _ _
```

Your program needs to accept a 2048 board, and return a truthy value if the board is reachable, else falsy.

//Explanation of 2048 goes here.

I've listed 4 different boards that cover major test cases.  Are there any others I'm missing?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: hehe, don't forget `[tag:sliding-puzzle]`

Comment: As you've stated yourself the main thing missing here is the bulk of the challenge.

Comment: I wonder if it suffices to look one step back, or if you need to check if the previous position can itself be produced.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a challenge, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it in a way that's on-topic. It's possible this type of question just doesn't mesh with PPCG, but that's what the SandBox is for, right?

The gist is that I want a sort implemented lazily. So lazily that you don't actually write one, you steal someone else's. Your code should take an input, find/scrape an existing sorting algorithm off StackExchange (just PPCG?), run it, and output the sorted list.

Here's what I've got so far:

## The Laziest Sort

I need a program that sorts a list, but man am I lazy. I don't mean "I'll just write a bubble sort and call it a day" lazy, but "I don't even want to write any sort at all" lazy. In fact, I don't even want to look at a sorting algorithm.

Given a list of numbers, I want you to return to me a sorted list. But like I said, I don't want to look a sorting algorithm. Instead, I want you to go find an existing sorting algorithm, run it, and tell me what it said.

## The rules (This is part of where I need the SandBox)

- You may **not** use any native sorting algorithms (like `Collections.sort()`).
- You **may** use any sorting algorithm you can find, so long as it is from StackExchange.
- You **may** import the code from the algorithm you use and run it from your answer, so long as the actual algorithm isn't in your source code.
- Anything other requirement this challenge needs? I feel like this describes the problem I have in mind, but I've only made a few questions and they're typically math/array based.

## Scoring

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) seems an odd tag here, but [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) seems to be frowned upon. Especially since I don't have a great question formed yet, but I feel like I've got a reasonable idea here. Any tips on how to get this question presentable enough to actually post?

Comment: Yeah, we have a tag for this. It's called [tag:duct-tape-coding]

Comment: I would use [tag:code-golf] for this personally.

Comment: You mean, implement [Stacksort](https://www.google.com/search?q=stacksort)? :) (not exactly the same, but very similar)

Answer (score 1):

## The Mode of an Image

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Given an image as input, output it's mode; that is the colour that appears most in it. However, I am on a tight schedule and so need this code to compute as fast as possible.

**Input**

Input can be in any reasonable format for your program i.e. filename or image object. However, the input image must have at least 3 channels i.e. `r`, `g`, `b` or 24bpp.

**Output**

Output can be by any reasonable means i.e. return of a method or print to STDOUT.

**Test Cases**

//TODO: add them

**Scoring**

As this is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) the winner is the answer which scores the lowest total time over all of the test cases. For example, if there are two test cases then the `score = timeForTestCase1 + timeForTestCase2`.

In the even that more than one winning answer scores the same more test cases will be added. The winning answers will be notified and should be updated accordingly.

## Sandbox

- Test case suggestions?
- Better scoring mechanism? i.e. average of the time for each test case

Comment: Will all input images be of the same dimensions?

Comment: @Cowsquack No they will vary

Answer (score 1):

## Left or Right?

You have a carousel of images, and you know the index of the image you wish to view.

The carousel shows a few images per page, so you need to be able to calculate if you need to move at all.

Also, the carousel wraps - so you can click 'right' on the last page to go to the first page, and 'left' on the first to go to the last.

The first image on the first page is at index 0 - and the last page may not, depending on the amount of images, always be full. If you prefer, you may start your indexing at 1 instead, but remember that the indexes in all of the example inputs will need to have 1 added to them.

### Input

4 numbers, in whatever format is suitable for your language;

- **Total** - The amount of images in the carousel (1 or greater)
- **PageSize** - The amount of images per section in the carousel
- **CurrentIndex** - The index of the image you are currently looking at (0 to Total-1)
- **DestinationIndex** - The index of the image you wish to look at.

### Output

The desired direction to scroll (if at all). This should be the fastest direction (ie least amount of clicks), desiring right in the case of a tie.

Either;

- **L** - Click the left button (ie, go backwards)
- **R** - Click the right button (ie, go forwards)
- **N** - No movement required - output this if the image you seek is on the same page as your current image.

If you prefer, you may specify 3 other distinct outputs, such as `-1` `0` and `1` for example.

### Examples

Say we have `5 3 0 4`, so 5 total images, a page size of 3, we're currently at image index 0, aiming for 4. Our carousel would look something like this:

```
< [0 1 2] >
```

Pressing either left or right (there are only 2 pages) would lead us to this:

```
< [ 3 4 ] >
```

On this page, we can see image 4 which we are aiming for, so in this example, you would be expected to return `R`. Although `L` is the same length, in this exercise we are to favour going right in the case of a tie. Also note that you are expected to return just the direction you would need to go, so if you would have to click `R` 3 times, still only return one `R`.

Here are some more test cases;

```
5 2 0 2 -> R
10 5 1 4 -> N
10 3 8 1 -> R
10 3 8 4 -> L
```

Comment: I think this is kind of easy for this is site. One suggestion I have is to make the carousel "broken", such that it moves by *n* pages per click, instead of 1. Then a fourth output would be "X", saying that it's impossible to reach a certain image.

Comment: You should allow 1-indexing and not force everyone to use 0-indexing. Also the first test case is returning `L` or `R` allowed or should you prefer to return `R` over `L` always?

Comment: @geokavel I don't think that's necessary, easy challenges are still good challenges.

Comment: Guess it's ok as is.

Comment: TheLethalCoder good point, I did mean to do that, but forgot to mention it. Also I did mention that in the first paragraph of the output section, but I'll reiterate it in the example paragraph you refer to. geokavel - Thanks for your input - but I personally would like to see a few more easier challenges on this site to encourage newbies (like myself)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - actually, using 1 based indexes would change the input as well. Do we still generally allow that when the *input* is going to change?

Comment: @shadow Yes we usually allow people to use 0 or 1 indexing irrespective of whether the input changes or not.

Comment: Could we output, for example, `1`, `-1`, and `0` instead of `R`, `L`, and `N`?

Comment: @StepHen - I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

## Smooth Usage [On hold while alternative scoring is considered]

We've all seen CPU usage graphs like this one:

[image: CPU Usage example]

Doesn't that look ugly?  It would look much nicer as a lovely smooth sine wave...

---

### Challenge

Write a program in the language of your choice that will infinitely produce a regular sine wave in Task Manager's (or Activity Monitor's if that's your thing) CPU usage graph.

**You may assume:**

- Background CPU usage is constant
- Only a single core must display the pattern
- The system has sufficient cooling to prevent thermal throttling
- Features such as Intel TurboBoost are disabled

This is tagged as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) to encourage short answers, but ultimately will be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) as I suspect perfect solutions will be hard to come by.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551494/write-code-to-make-cpu-usage-display-a-sine-wave

Comment: [tag:code-golf] and [tag:popularity-contest] don't mix together. You have to choose one or the other, but making it strictly [tag:code-golf] would be difficult because you'd have to define what is a good enough sine wave, but on the other hand popularity contests are very risky to do.

Comment: @dzaima That was exactly my dilemma - which would you suggest fits the challenge best?

Comment: I'd say a scoring algorithm of some sort would be best for this, no idea how you'd do it. Like the related one was objective. If you could read the word, it was valid. With this, is a bumpy sin-wave a sin-wave?

Comment: @MTCoster If you're not sure whether [tag:popularity-contest] fits, then you can be sure that it does not. It is quite difficult to make an well received one. Go with [tag:code-golf] or make a [tag:code-challenge] if you can come up with a *good* own winning criterion.

Answer (score 1):

### Archer Battle

Your challenge is to simulate a battle between two armies of archers.

Each army has a population and an accuracy. Each round, every archer will let fly an arrow at the enemy army. The archers are trained each to shoot at different targets. Any archer hit by an enemy arrow is eliminated, and is does not participate in the next round. The battle is over when all archers in one or both armies have been eliminated.

The accuracy of the archers is almost exact. That is, `ceil(population * accuracy)` arrows will hit their targets. (No need to use random number generation.)

### Input

Take 4 inputs in any reasonable manner:

- Army 1 population (positive integer)
- Army 2 population (positive integer)
- Army 1 accuracy (nonnegative float)
- Army 2 accuracy (nonnegative float)

### Output

Output the population of the winning army at the end of the battle.

Comment: What if there are more archers than targets, and so they can't all shoot at different targets?

Comment: @isaacg Good point. I suppose "every archer selecting a different target" doesn't match the model perfectly. Perhaps "The archers distribute their targets among the opposing army as evenly as possible." and "`ceil(population * accuracy) enemies will be struck by arrows (capped at the remaining population of the opposing army, of course)."

Any suggestions on improving the wording? And would a sample program help?

Answer (score 1):

## Reverse Cycling with Rubik's [rubiks-cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

In [Cycling with Rubik's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70952/61563), you were asked to find the period of a given sequence of turns - or, in Geobits' words:

> Given a sequence of turns, [find] the fewest number of times it must be performed to return the cube to its original state.

Today, I'm asking you to do the opposite.

Terms you might not know:

- "algorithm": a sequence of moves on the faces of a Rubik's cube
- "period": the minimum number of times an algorithm must be repeated before a solved cube returns to the solved state

## Input

The input will be the period of a Rubik's cube algorithm. This is an integer between 1 and 1260, as any algorithm can be performed 0 times, and the highest possible period for any given algorithm is 1260.

## Output

The output will be any algorithm that has a period equal to the input. Algorithms should use standard notation, namely:

```
R - Turn the right face clockwise 90°
L - Turn the left face clockwise 90°
U - Turn the up (top) face clockwise 90°
D - Turn the down (bottom) face clockwise 90°
F - Turn the front face clockwise 90°
B - Turn the back face clockwise 90°
```

Adding the prime mark `'` to the end of any move changes it from a clockwise rotation to a counterclockwise one, so `F'` turns the front face counterclockwise, and `F F'` would return it to the original state right away.

If you're still confused about face turns, you can check out [this](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/).

## Examples

```
Input -> Output
1     -> FF'
4     -> R
4     -> UD
6     -> RUR'U'
12    -> LLUUFFUURRUU
56    -> LUFFRDRBF
105   -> LF
120   -> UFFR'DBBRL'
315   -> FRBL
1260  -> U1R3U1F3D2
```

## Winner

As with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the least bytes wins! As this is very difficult (it might be impossible), I will give a +50 bounty to the first answer, or +100 if it's under 100 bytes. Good luck!

Comment: The order of the Rubik's cube group is 2²⁷ 3¹⁴ 5³ 7² 11, so by Lagrange's theorem there's no algorithm of order 13.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is the same true for any other prime?

Comment: @H.PWiz, the same is true for any other number which isn't a factor of the order of the group. I'm not sure whether subgroups exist for all factors smaller than the largest order of an element. Certainly they do for all prime factors, by Sylow's theorems.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't know any group theory, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm.. unlike the _Cyling with Rubik's_ challenge, this one can only be solved by bruteforce if I understand correctly? Also, what's with the `R3` and `F3` in the `1260` test case? These can just be `R'` or `F'`. Or if you are allowing `3` instead of `'` as output, I would mention it somewhere in the challenge. Off-topic: But it's funny that my Rubik's cube logo is almost next to your challenge title, since I posted the previous sandbox answer. ;p

Answer (score 1):

## Detect Ambiguity in a Context-Free Grammar

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [grammars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars)

Sandbox notes:

- Is the background too hard to understand? If so, should I clarify it further at the risk of making it unreasonably long, or simply delete it and state that the reader should have a knowledge of context-free grammars?
- Is there anything I should clarify in the specifications?
- Are there any other tags I should add? I couldn't find any better ones.
- Should I add more test cases?
- Apparently at the moment this problem is undecidable (which I found out *way* too late). Would this problem be decidable if I let solutions assume that ambiguous grammars will always have an unambiguous counterpart (in other words, the program will never be given an [inherently ambiguous grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ambiguous_grammar&oldid=766721746#Inherently_ambiguous_languages)?

### Background

A [Context-Free Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) (CFG) is a set of rules for constructing strings. For example, the following is a CFG describing BF:

> *prog* → *command* | *command* *prog*
>   *command* → `+` | `-` | `,` | `.` | `<` | `>` | *loop*
>   *loop* → `[` *prog* `]`

Let's see how the BF program `,[-]` can be constructed using this grammar:

[image: Parse tree for a context-free grammar]

Wikipedia formally defines a grammar as a group of four items:

- A set of *nonterminals*, which are the "variables". In the example above, these are *prog*, *command*, and *loop*.
- A set of *terminals*, which are symbols in the alphabet that strings are composed of. In the example above, these are the BF program characters `+-,.<>[]`.
- A set of *production rules*, which define what nonterminals are allowed to become. Each rule consists of a *head*, which is a nonterminal, and a *body*, which is a list of terminals and nonterminals. In the example above, these are the production rules:

  - *prog* → *command*
  - *prog* → *command* *prog*
  - *command* → `+`
  - *command* → `-`
  - ...
  - *command* → *loop*
  - *loop* → `[` *prog* `]`
- One nonterminal that serves as the starting point for the grammar (in other words, the root node in the parse tree). In the example above, this is *prog*.

Consider the following context-free grammar:

> *bitstring* → *bit* | *bit* *bitstring*
>   *bit* → `1` | `0`

It may be tempting to collapse the two lines:

> *bitstring* → `1` | `0` | *bitstring* *bitstring*

The disadvantage of this representation over the original is that it is *ambiguous* - that is, given a string, it is possible to deriving that string in multiple different ways. For example, in this grammar, the string `101` may be derived as `((10)1)` or `(1(01))`.

The problem with ambiguity is that there is not a single way to create a representation of the generation process, which is useful for e.g. parse trees.

### A useful subset of CFGs

To make CFGs easier to manipulate, we will constrain them in this way:

- Restrict the alphabet of terminals to `0` and `1`,
- Identify nonterminals by a number rather than a name (either 0- or 1-indexed),
- Assume the first nonterminal (0 or 1 depending on indexing scheme) to be the initial one.

In this way, we have reduced the description of a CFG down to two inputs:

- A number representing the quantity of nonterminals
- A list of production rules, which is a list of pairs (*head*, *body*), where *head* designates a nonterminal for the head, and *body* is a list of terms which can be terminals or nonterminals.

### The Task

Given a representation of a context-free grammar as described above, output a truthy or falsey value representing whether the grammar is ambiguous.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (measured in *bytes* wins).

### Specifications

- You can use any two distinct non-empty strings instead of `1` and `0` for the terminals.
- You can assume the lists representing the bodies of the production rules are nonempty.
- You may take input in any reasonable format. If you are taking input as a number and a list and your language does not support mixed-type lists, you can assume the existence of two special nonterminals that represent the terminals `0` and `1`. If this is done, please specify the two nonterminals in your answer.
- You can assume that every nonterminal can "halt", that is, be mapped to a finite string of nonterminals. This means that you will never get an input like:

  > *string* → `0` *string* | `1` *string*

  This also means that every nonterminal must have at least one production rule.
- Keep in mind that production rules are technically a *set*. The order of the rules is not relevant, so your program should be able to handle them in any order.
- You can assume there will be less than 100 production rules, and therefore less than 100 distinct nonterminals.
- You can assume that the input will be a well-formed CFG in whatever input format you designate.

### Test Cases

In these examples, nonterminals are zero-indexed.

#### Ambiguous (Truthy)

---

Only empty strings:

```
1, [
    (0, []),
    (0, [0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →  | *string*

---

Any string of bits:

```
1, [
    (0, []),
    (0, ["0"]),
    (0, ["1"]),
    (0, [0, 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →  | `1` | `0` | *string* *string*

---

Nonempty strings of ones, separated by zeroes:

```
2, [
    (1, ["1"]),
    (1, ["1", 1]),
    (0, [1]),
    (0, [0, "0", 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* → *ones* | *string* `0` *string*
>   *ones* → `1` | `1` *ones*

---

Odd-length strings of bits:

```
1, [
    (0, ["0"]),
    (0, ["1"]),
    (0, [0, 0, 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* → `0` | `1` | *string* *string* *string*

---

`1` and `0` balanced like parenthesis:

```
1, [
    (0, []),
    (0, ["1", 0, "0"]),
    (0, [0, 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →  | `1` *string* `0` | *string* *string*

---

#### Unambiguous (Falsey)

---

Only empty strings:

```
1, [
    (0, [])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →

---

Any string of bits:

```
1, [
    (0, []),
    (0, ["0", 0]),
    (0, ["1", 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →  | `0` *string* | `1` *string*

---

Nonempty strings of ones, separated by zeroes:

```
0, [
    (0, [1]),
    (0, [1, "0", 0]),
    (1, ["1"]),
    (1, ["1", 1])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* → *ones* | *ones* `0` *string*
>   *ones* → `1` | `1` *ones*

---

Odd-length strings of bits:

```
2, [
    (0, [1]),
    (0, [1, 1, 0]),
    (1, ["0"]),
    (1, ["1"])
]
```

> *string* → *bit* | *bit* *bit* *string*
>   *bit* → `0` | `1`

---

`1` and `0` balanced like parenthesis:

```
1, [
    (0, []),
    (0, ["1", 0, "0", 0])
]
```

Readable form:

> *string* →  | `1` *string* `0` *string*

---

Comment: I think the CFG is described quite well, but the "useful subset" seems a little confusing - you restrict terminals to `[0,1]` and non-terminals to numbers and say "...body is a list of terms which can be terminals or nonterminals", but in the examples you have bodies containing quoted numbers.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, the quoted ones are terminals, and the unquoted ones are indices of nonterminals. I might change that if it turns out to be too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

## Just a relative

### Summary

Produce a piece of golfed code that will take a spreadsheet formula and a translation vector and adjust any cell references in the formula by the translation vector.

### Rules

What you need to create is a program that takes 2 inputs. A string formula and a representation of the transformation the formula is to undergo (i.e: 1 1 (column, row)).

Invalid inputs include, but are not limited too, inputs with invalid cell references, translations that produce invalid references (see definitions) and formulas formulas that don't start with an equals sign.

The output should be the formula with its' cell references transformed as per the rules above. Input types are flexible, but the output should be a string with no leading/trailing whitespace.

### Definitions

> #### Cell Reference
>
> An alphanumeric string that within spreadsheet software, indicates the cells position on a 2D grid.
> They consist of two parts, an alphabetic segment a numeric segment.
>
> The alphabetic segment represents the column position of the cell. It can be of any length, with each character belonging to the 26 letter English alphabet and is case insensitive. A numerical mapping of the column position can be attained using 26-adic bijective numeration.
>
> The numeric segment represents the row position of the cell, and must be a positive non-zero integer.
>
> It is also valid for the dollar `$` symbol to appear in a cell reference. A single one is valid preceding both the alphabetic and numeric segments either independently or simultaneously. A dollar preceding the alphabetic segment indicates an invariant column under transformation, and a dollar preceding the numeric segment indicates an invariant row under transformation.
>
> #### Function
>
> An arbitrarily named reference to some set of instructions.
>
> For the purpose of this challenge, these are defined as a case insensitive alphanumeric string followed by an open and closed set of rounded brackets. Within these brackets, arbitrary arguments can be present including other functions, arbitrary values and cell references. Arguments are comma seperated.
>
> Example: `CALCULATEBYTES('mycodegolfanswer', A1)`
>
> #### Formula
>
> A calculation composed of arbitrary numeric operators, functions, values, cell references etc.
>
> A formula must be started with an equals `=` sign and can then be followed by anything except for a numeric operator.

### Examples

```
=SUMIFS(A1, "=2") 1 1
>>=SUMIFS(B2, "=2")

=SUMIFA1(GL93) 1 2
>>=SUMIFA1(GM95)

=ARBITRARY($A$1)+CRAZY(G$3) 3 3
>>=ARBITRARY($A$1)+CRAZY(J$3)

=$A3+B$2+$C$1 4 -2
>>=$A1+F$2+$C$1
```

Hope this all makes sense!

Winner is the shortest code in bytes, but bonus kudos if anyone posts a golfed answer in punch card Fortran!

Happy golfing!

Comment: 1. The post is a bit "wall of text"-ey. Maybe separate out all the description of what references are from the main challenge a little? 2. You talk about using `$` for absolute referencing but don't mention them in the challenge or give any test cases for them. 3. It's normal in code-golf to assume input will be valid or (almost equivalently) allow any behaviour upon receiving invalid input (I'd suggest one of these). If you do keep an actual "error requirement" you should state if it should be the string "error" or an actual error and probably add a reason for the error to the test case(s).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the feedback. Amended based on what you said

Answer (score 1):

## Conversion: 2 dice from 3

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [probability](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)

---

This [fascinating video from Matt Parker's standupmaths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E) poses a challenge:

Given the result of rolling 3 indistinguishable (unordered) dice, simulate the result of rolling 2 indistinguishable (unordered) dice.

For the purposes of this challenge, simply [returning the sum of 2 dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80095/three-indistinguishable-dice) is not sufficient. Returning 2 *ordered* dice *is* acceptable, as the order can be ignored so this still fulfils the requirement.

## Input

Either 3 unordered values from 1 to 6, or 3 ordered values from 1 to 6. If the values are ordered, then the output must be independent of the input order. For example, the input `1, 2, 3` should give the same output as the input `2, 1, 3`.

These are standard dice. Your code may not assume the values will be from 0 to 5 instead of 1 to 6.

## Output

Either 2 unordered values from 1 to 6, or 2 ordered values from 1 to 6. If the values are ordered, then different orderings will be considered ***equivalent***. For example, output `1, 2` is equivalent to output `2, 1`.

Given input that matches the probability distribution of rolling 3 dice, the probability distribution of the output must match that of rolling 2 dice.

You can choose to calculate the outputs however you wish, provided that they are deterministic (the same input in any order gives ***equivalent*** output). That is, different answers may use different mappings. So for input `1, 2, 3`, one answer may give output `4, 5`, while another answer may give output `5, 6`. Provided all outputs occur in the correct proportions, both answers are valid.

The output must also use standard dice. Your code may not output values from 0 to 5 instead of 1 to 6.

## Checking for correctness

One simple but laborious way of checking that the outputs occur in the correct proportions is to consider all 216 possible *ordered* triples as inputs. This automatically accounts for the fact that the unordered triple `1, 2, 3` is 6 times more likely to come up that the unordered triple `1, 1, 1`, since it will occur as 6 different ordered triples (the 6 different ways of arranging 1, 2, and 3).

A valid answer will give the same output (apart from order) regardless of the order of the input, and will give any given double such as `1, 1` for exactly 6 of the ordered inputs, and any given distinct pair such as `1, 2` (equivalently `2, 1`) for exactly 12 of the ordered inputs.

## Scoring

The original puzzle was asking for an easy way for humans to calculate this in their heads during playing a game. This challenge is instead [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the score is the number of bytes in your code, and the lowest score in a given language wins.

## Prior work

This was also [posted on puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/make-2-dice-out-of-3-dice) and there are a number of approaches there. Although they are aimed at being human usable, there may be some insights there that are relevant to writing short code.

## Test cases

As every answer may use a different mapping, there is no way to generate meaningful test cases for this challenge. The simplest way I can think to test is as described above under "Checking for correctness".

---

## Sandbox questions

- I've just discovered [this previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80095/three-indistinguishable-dice) which is based on the same video. It asks only for the sum of 2 dice, rather than an unordered pair, so is not identical. Is this a sufficient difference to avoid this being a duplicate, and would it be different enough to be worthwhile posting?

Comment: Even if it's not officially a dupe I'd still like feedback on whether it's different enough to be interesting.

Comment: Looking at the Jelly answer, I think the change required for this question is to remove the final character. So yes, it does fail the dupe test.

Answer (score 1):

## Brain-Flak Golfing Tournament

*This is a very rough draft.  I am looking for as much feedback as possible while I flesh out this challenge*

Welcome to the first ever Brain-Flak Golfing Tournament.

This tournament will have 2 phases.  The first being a call for challenges and the second being the competition.  Any user may participate in either, both or, of course, neither of the phases.

### Challenge submissions

In this first phase users can submit mini challenges to be used in the competition.  These will be of two varieties,

- [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)
- [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

I've chosen these varieties because they tend to be the commonly agreed most "fun" tags for Brain-Flak. (SANDBOX: If you have any qualms these varieties are variable)

#### Kolmogorov-complexity

Kolmogorov complexity challenges, like the name implies, should provide a constant string to be output with no input.  For example `Hiya there earth!`.

As a personal style point I find Kolmogorov complexity is most fun for strings of 10-20 characters.  However feel free to answer of whatever size you think would be interesting

#### Sequence

For sequence challenges you should you should choose a sequence from the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/), and provide its number and a brief description in the body of your answer.

Answers to sequence mini challenges will take n and output the nth term of the sequence.  You may specify what indexings are permitted in your answer.  Since OEIS sequences are not well specified on their own answers will only be required to support as high as are provided in the b-files of that sequence.

As a personal style point Brain-Flak is especially good at computing challenges involving or related to [polygonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number), however variety is always welcome.

---

In addition to providing a challenge you must also provide a "par".  A par will be a program that satisfies the requirements of your mini-challenge.  The purpose of a par is two-fold:

- It proves your mini-challenge is reasonably possible
- It provides a default score for more casual participants who might not necessarily answer all the mini-challenges, or more serious users who run out of time.

Your par should *not* be your own best attempt at a challenge, it should be beatable otherwise participants would just score the par and you might as well have not made the challenge at all.

Lastly no mini-challenge should correspond to a preexisting PPCG that already has a Brain-Flak answer.  For example *do not* submit print `Hello, World!` as a challenge, because we have already have very competitive solutions.  Unlike earlier suggestions this will be enforced.

### Challenge answers

In the second phase users will answer challenges made in the first phase.  You will have one week to craft an answer in (relative) secrecy, at the end of the week answers will be revealed and a winner declared.  You will have to have an answer on this question prior to the reveal.

All that is required of answers before the reveal are the following two things

- A rundown of the byte counts.  This should be your scores to each mini challenge not including ones posed by your self.  If you choose not to complete a single challenge for any reason you should take the par as your score for that challenge.
- A hash.  This should be a SHA-256 hash of a string containing all of your solutions on separate lines and your ppcg user id.  You may include other information in the string to throw off potential attackers if you wish, but it should not resemble any of the required elements.

These are the only two things that are required, however if you would like to include additional hints to other users you may do so, just don't reveal your own solutions ahead of time as that can make the challenge rather un-fun.

You may continuously update your answer anytime before the reveal.

You should not at any point lie about contents that are hidden.  Accusations will be dealt with on a case by case basis, but if you are caught having lied you will be disqualified.

### Scoring

*This is still a work in progress right now its just a plan*

I plan to base scoring based on [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)).  Normally it would just be the sum of individual challenges but because one cannot fairly compete in their own challenges things have to be a little bit more sophisticated.  Once I decide on a good scoring system I will add a code snippet to help calculate rankings.

Scoring will obviously be based on byte counts with less being better.

### Prizes

I will be offering 3 bounties for exceptional participants

- 500 rep for the overall winner of the challenge
- 200 rep for the runner up of the challenge
- 100 rep for the top voted mini challenge

Answer (score 1):

## Program an Uncircularness Score

[derivative of this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14410/24877)

### Meta:

This is just a rough idea for a slightly different challenge. I have no idea how successfull it would be in the current state, so feel free to share your opinions and suggestions.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Your task is to program a mathematical function `s`, that takes a finite set `A` of points in the 2D plane, and outputs an uncircularity score `s(A)` that satisfies following properties:

1. *positive definiteness*: If there is a circle or a straight line that contains all points of `A`, then `s(A) = 0`. Otherwise `s(A) > 0`
2. It is surjective to the nonnegative real numbers, that means for every nonnegative real number `r` there is a finite subset `A` of the plane such that `s(A) = r`.

#### Scoring

You get one point for every of the following properties that your function (provably) has.

- *Translation Invariance:* `s` is translation invariant if `s(A) = s(A + v)` for every vector `v` and for all `A`.
- *Scale Invariance:* `s` is scale invariant, if `s(A) = s(A * t)` for every `t≠0` and for all `A`.
- *Monotony:* `s` is monotonous if `s(A) ≤ s(B)` for all `A,B` where `A ⊆ B`.
- *Circle Inversion Invariance:* `s` is circle inversion invariant, if `s(A) = s(f(A))` for all `A` with `0 ∉ A`, where `f(x,y) = (x/(x^2+y^2), y/(x^2+y^2))` is the [circle inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion). (Here `(x,y)` represent the cartesian coordinates of a point in the plane.)
- *Triangle inequality:* `s` satisfies the "triangle inequality" if `s(A ∩ B) ≤ s(A) + s(B)` for all `A,B`. (This is implied by Monotony.)
- *Reverse triangle inequality:* `s` satisfies the "reverse triangle inequality" if `s(A) + s(B) ≤ s(A ∪ B)` for all `A,B`.
- *Continuity.* `s` is said to be *continuous* if the function `f(p) := s(A ∪ {p})` (mapping the a point `p` to a real number) is continuous using the standard absolute value on the real numbers, and the standard euclidean norm on the points of the plane.
- More to come...

Comment: Perhaps you should change the "non-negative real number" to "non-negative rational number" or "non-negative algebraic number" in part 2.  If these functions are being produced by code it seems quite unreasonable to expect numbers that cannot be represented in computer memory to be output.

Comment: @WheatWizard That's an interesting thought. Personally I quite like the idea of these properties working over the real numbers in theory, and the code implementing it to a desired accuracy of approximation, but I'm not sure if that's easier or harder to score/judge valid.

Comment: @trichoplax I will admit I am opposed to any "code must work in theory" rules in challenges.  However any code that works in theory must also work on the reals or algebraics which allows us to have code that works not just in theory.

Comment: @WheatWizard I agree that asking for testable solutions is much more satisfactory than "works in theory".

Comment: I guess "provably" needs to be defined in the context of the challenge. Will there be a defined method of testing or does this require a mathematical proof (in which case it leans more towards puzzling's scope).

Comment: @WheatWizard That is a good point that I did not think about. But I'd allow for limited precision implementations (i.e. floating point), because everything else would probably almost make the challenge impossible.

Comment: @trichoplax You'd need a *lot* of testcases to be convincing, but I think the participants should be able (they don't have to write down proofs) to provide good arguments for why a certain property is satisfied, just as we require any program to be actually doing what it is supposed to do. (we don't require proof of correctness either)

Comment: I think trichoplax makes a good point.  I'm not sure how much this is really about code.  It might be a better idea to post this on puzzling as a math puzzle where you need only define a function rather than some code.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks. I think this could be made into a code-challenge (or code-golf), but it could also be made into a mathematical function challenge like you suggest. I can't guess which would be more interesting (or easier to define objectively) though. I suppose there's nothing stopping it being two challenges, one on each site...

Comment: Translation and scale invariance are easily added: translate to put the centroid at the origin and then if there's more than two points scale so that the furthest point from the origin is at distance 1 from the origin; then apply the original function. It might be possible to deliberately construct a noncircularity function such that this would destroy the surjectivity, but in practice I don't think the question would be harmed by assuming that all answers will be affine-invariant and simplifying the scoring system appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) OR [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode) [decode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decode)

## Steganography: Hide a message in an image!

---

## Cops

You will want to see the [Default acceptable image I/O methods for image related challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/58826).

Your challenge is to write a program that takes a string and an image as input and somehow encodes the string in the image. You output the image.

You must also make a program that reverses the above: it takes a image, and outputs the original string (you don't need to output the original image).

Your encoder must work on *any* string, but it only needs to work on one type of image.

Post the encoder (but not the decoder), and preferably a few image / string input / output examples.

Your post is cracked when someone makes a program that can take an outputted image and find the string hidden in it. **It doesn't have to be the decoder you intended. It can even be in another language.**

Once your submission is cracked, edit in a link to the crack and your decoder program.

If, after a week, nobody* has cracked your submission, edit in that you are safe, and edit in your decoder.

*[This](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/DeCSS/Gallery/Stego/index.html) may provide ideas!*

<sup>*not [Nobody](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64499/nobody)</sup>

---

## Robbers

Your challenge is to find a cop post and crack it.

To crack a cop post, you make a program that reverses what cops do:

> Your challenge is to write a program that takes a string and an image as input and somehow encodes the string in the image. You output the image.

In other words, your program takes an image and extracts the encoded string out of it. You don't have to output the image with or without the string.

Once you have cracked a cop's post, add a link in a comment.

The robber with the most cracks wins.

---

## Meta:

- Dupe? ([I don't think so](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers+graphical-output))
- Winning criterion for cops:

  **I really want this to be a pop-con.** Pop-cons are *hard* but I think I have [everything needed for a good pop-con](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info) covered:

  - > A challenge with clear specifications that still allow for creative problem solving. *I think this is clear but gives you freedom in how you encode a string.*
  - > A challenge where solutions that best solve the problem are also solutions that the voters are going to like. *I think that voters will enjoy very creative 'encoding's.*
  - > Gives freedom to entrants to decide what to do in crucial parts and incentivizes them to use this freedom. *You have complete freedom to pick how you hide the string. If you use a boring form of encoding, your encoder will quickly be cracked, but if you use your freedom to make a very creative encoder your submission will likely be safe.*
  - > It is strongly suggested to submit the challenge to the Sandbox at least a few days before posting the challenge. That way the challenge can be reviewed and discussed in order to find any mistakes or inconsistencies, and it also serves for getting a first impression whether the challenge will be well recieved. *Yep, I think this is covered.*

  And [what MUST be included in a pop-con](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info):

  - > A popularity contest must always include an objective validity criterion, which is a set of rules that regulate what every answer must comply with. Answers that do not comply are invalid and will be removed. *Yep, if you have a valid, working decoder than your stenography is reversible and therefore valid. If a week passes and you didn't have a decoder, your submission will be removed.*
  - > A clear specification of the goal that must be achieved. Questions like "*do (this) the most creative way*" should be avoided. Creativity should be the tool, not the goal. *Yep, the goal is to make a program that encodes a string in an image...*

  And [Qualities which should be AVOIDED in popularity contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info):

  - > Asking to solve a specific task in a very specific way, without room for creativity. *There is room for creativity within bounds in how your encoder works.*
  - > Asking to solve a vaguely defined task in any way that the entrant wants (this will probably make your question be closed as too broad). *Nope, you have the specific task of encoding a string in an image.*
  - > Rules what people should consider when voting. In the past this has consistently never worked out. These sort of questions would be better off as a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) with specific winning criteria. *Nope, I don't have any of these.*

  If there's anything I'm missing, please tell me. **I think this is a on-topic valid pop-con.** However, if it isn't, I'd be OK with making this a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

  However, PPCG has too much code golf. We need more variety in the challenges we have here. I hope this will provide an example of a valid pop-con.

Comment: Looking at the page you linked, you could also make this an image-polyglot challenge. Output an image of [something] that also does some other tasks when run in different languages. However, I don't really get your question about code-golf vs pop-con. This is a cops-n-robbers, which is usually won by being the first entry to go X days w/o being cracked.

Comment: @geokavel most cops-n-robbers I've seen are shortest safe cop, not earliest cop. So he's probably doing highest-voted safe cop.

Comment: pop-con's are usually good for graphical output, but here if I understand correctly, the viewer will not be able to see that you manipulated the image just by looking at it. So it lacks the intuitiveness useful for pop-cons.

Comment: This fails my first test for "*Is it a bad CnR?*": it's easy to make a cop which uses RSA and can't be cracked within a week on current hardware without spending serious money.

Answer (score 1):

## Generating Punnett Squares [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The task will be to generate a simple (monohybrid cross) [Punnett Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square), given the "genotype" of two parents.

A "trait" will be represented as a single alphabetical character (eg `'a'`).

An allele for a trait is that character, but if the allele is **dominant** if it is uppercased, and **recessive** if lowercased (eg `'a'` or `'A'`).

A genotype is two alleles, both of which can be either dominant or recessive. Note that if a genotype is heterozygous (has one dominant and one recessive allele) the dominant allele will always come first (eg `"AA"` or `"Aa"` or `"aa"`).

The input will be two strings of length 2, each of which is a valid genotype for one trait. You can take input as arguments to your function or program, or from a file. You should output a Punnett Square in exactly this format:

```
  A  a
A AA Aa
a Aa aa
```

(This would have been for the input `"Aa"` and `"Aa"`). The output can be to `stdout`, as a string, or to a file.

The first parent (which is the first argument) should be across the top, and the second parent should be down the side, so for the input `"AA"` and `"aa"`, the output should be:

```
  A  A
a Aa Aa
a Aa Aa
```

Your code is expected to work with any trait (letter of the alphabet).

Another way to phrase this problem might be to output a table of the cartesian product of two strings of length 2, where each string consists of only uppercase or lowercase variants of one character, and the data in each cell should be sorted such that each uppercase character comes before each lowercase character.

Full sample of behaviour for some trait "a":

```
"AA", "AA" ->

  A  A
A AA AA
A AA AA

"AA", "Aa" ->

  A  A
A AA AA
a Aa Aa

"AA", "aa" ->

  A  A
a Aa Aa
a Aa Aa

"Aa", "AA" ->

  A  a
A AA Aa
A AA Aa

"Aa", "Aa" ->

  A  a
A AA Aa
a Aa aa

"Aa", "aa" ->

  A  a
a Aa aa
a Aa aa

"aa", "AA" ->

  a  a
A Aa Aa
A Aa Aa

"aa", "Aa" ->

  a  a
A Aa Aa
a aa aa

"aa", "aa" ->

  a  a
a aa aa
a aa aa
```

This is my first attempt at a challenge so I'd like some feedback on if it's any good and how it can be improved. I haven't been able to find any challenge like this, so hopefully it's not a duplicate.

Have I explained it clearly?

Is this idea interesting enough for a challenge?

What other tags would I use with such a challenge?

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76661/194

Comment: Darn, you're right - I hadn't found it as I'd only searched for "punnet square". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Displaying exponent towers in ASCII

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[arithmatic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmatic)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

### Background

Unlike `+` and `*`, the exponentiation operator `^` is not associative. The convention is that `^` is right associative, so that `a^(b^c) = a^b^c`. Of course, nested exponentials are usually displayed as nested superscripts, which can be represented in ASCII as:

```
            c
           b
a^(b^c) = a
```

For a general right associative operator `&`, there would be no way to simplify the expression `(a&b)&c`. However, exponentiation satisfies the rule

```
           bc
(a^b)^c = a
```

where `bc` means `b*c`.

Combining these rules, we can express any arbitrarily parenthesized exponential expression using only superscripts and juxtaposition. For example,

```
                                               d
                                              c  f
                                             b  e
(a^(b^(c^d)))^(e^f) = a^((b^(c^d))*(e^f)) = a
```

### Challenge

Write a function that, given a string consisting of lowercase letters, parentheses, and `^` that represents a valid mathematical expression (see rules), prints an ASCII representation of this expression in the manner described above.

### Rules

- The input string is any element of the context-free grammar determined by the rules
  `S → any lowercase letter`
  `S → (S^S)`
- The output must consist of only lowercase letters, spaces and newlines.
- The resulting ASCII picture must have exactly one letter per column.
- The left to right order of the letters must be preserved from input to output.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

```
Input: a
Output:
a

Input: (a^(b^c))
Output:
  c
 b
a

Input: ((a^b)^(c^d))
Output:
   d
 bc
a

Input: ((a^(b^c))^d)
Output:
  c
 b d
a
```

### Meta

- Is it clear what picture you are supposed to output?
- This challenge has some similarities to this other challenge, but I think they are far enough part to not be dupes: [Convert exponents into ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86647/convert-exponents-into-ascii-art).

Answer (score 1):

## [Erdős–Straus conjecture](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142349/erd%C5%91s-straus-conjecture)

Comment: Can you give me the answer for n=7777 . How much time did it take your program  to find it? What do you mean by "result must be returned for all valid inputs".Is 1500 years ok for bigger n? Brute-forcing this is very easy but it takes forever.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I'll put a reasonable limit and the last part means you need to output the right numbers if `x` is valid (a whole number larger than 2)

Answer (score 1):

## Pythagorean Double Regex

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

[Posted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39913942#39913942) by [NH.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/255519/nh) in [Zendo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63829/zendo):

> though depending on the regex flavor, things like that pythagorean triple could be hard to do.

The rule in question was:

> Given a pair of numbers, match if the two numbers are part of some integral Pythagorean triple, else don't match.

### Challenge

Given a pair of positive integers, write a regex that matches if and only if the pair of integers are part of a Pythagorean triple - i.e. if the two integers are `a` and `b`, either `a2+b2` is a perfect square or `|a2-b2|` is. (Note: `x,x` should match, even though `0,x,x` is not a true Pythagorean triple)

### Input

- Integers represented in any base, separated by a character not used in the representation of that base

### Test cases

<sup>NB: All but one of these test cases were taken from the game of Zendo from which the rule came, so they may not test boundary cases of the rule</sup>

```
True:
3,4
4,3
30,40
16,12
20,21
21,20
4,5
40,50
24,25
7,7

False:
1,2
5,6
7,8
4,10
9,10
3,100
9,16
24,20
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest regex in bytes wins!

Comment: 1. Ideally a question should be self-contained. This barely makes sense without following the links. I'm not even sure whether the answers have to be regexes or whether that was just the original context. 2. What's the scoring system / winning criterion?

Comment: @PeterTaylor is this better?

Comment: Definitely improved, yes. I'm still not sure what "*(from the game)*" refers to. Also, are you taking into account that by default we consider unary to be an acceptable input format for positive integers when writing a regex? I advise being explicit about whether numbers must be in decimal or whether unary is acceptable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor fixed up again

Answer (score 1):

## Determine the Resultant

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra)[polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

## META:

I'm not yet sure which one of the following two versions would be more interesting:

**Version a**: Given two integral polynomials `P,Q` determine their resultant `Res(P,Q)`.

**Version b**: Given two monic integral polynomials `P,Q` determine the polynomials `A,B` such that `AP+BQ = Res(P,Q)`. Where `deg A < deg Q` and `deg B < deg P`.

#### Definitions

The resultant is defined as

[image]

Here the product iterates over all complex numbers pairs that are zeros of each polynomial. For integral polyonmials this is an integer. (One other way - and certainly not the only - is via the determinant given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition).) The corresponding integral polynomials `A,B` such that `AP+BQ = Res(P,Q)` with `deg A < deg Q` and `deg B < deg P` are unique.

Comment: Are these polynomials on **Z**? You say complex number pairs which suggests it is some numeric set.

Comment: Those pairs are not necessarily integers, but the polynomials are.

Answer (score 1):

## Align the Words

Given a list of words `l` output them as follows:

- Iterate through `l`, if it's the first word, output it as usual.
- If it's not the first word, iterate through this nth word and:

  - Find the first letter of word `n` that's in word `n-1`.
  - Align the first occurrence of that letter in word `n` with the first occurrence in word `n-1` and print it on the next line.

---

## Worked Example

**Input:** `[ace,face,please,keep,sheeple]`

```
1: ace

2:  ace
   face

3:  ace
   face
    please

4:  ace
   face
    please
     keep

5:  ace
   face
    please
     keep
    sheeple

[Note: You only print step #5, the rest is to show the process.]
```

---

## Rules

- Lowest byte-count wins, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- All consecutive words in the input list `l` will have at least 1 letter in common.

  - If the input is invalid, any return is fine (error, nothing, etc...)
- A word is defined here as a collection of `a-z` (lowercase ONLY alpha characters).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90957/42963), not a dupe.

Comment: To be clear, are we to output every step along the way, or just the final arrangement? If every step along the way, what's an appropriate separator?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork final product, should make that clear I s'pose.

Comment: Are we allowed to use uppercase only instead of lowercase only as well? Not really relevant for the programming language I usually golf in, but I can imagine it's relevant for some programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

## 100 Letters is the Perfect Amount

Oxford dictionary lists the most commonly used English letters in the following order:

```
EARIOTNSLCUDPMHGBFYWKVXZJQ
```

And assigns each the following frequencies:

[image: Distribution of the letters...]

For the purpose of this challenge, the diagram will be simplified as follows:

```
z   1
q   1
x   1
j   1
k   1
v   1
b   2
p   2
y   2
g   2
f   2
w   2
m   3
u   3
c   3
l   4
d   4
r   5
h   6
s   6
n   6
i   6
o   7
a   8
t   9
e   12
TOT 100
```

---

Now, onto the task at hand; I've provided you all with a [dictionary of words to choose from](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength/blob/master/unsorted.txt), using this dictionary of words choose as many as you want to output. However the catch is that you must have **EXACTLY** the count above of each letter in the output using 7-12 words.

---

## Scoring

- Your base score is the length of your code in bytes.
- You are allowed to go over or under on the number of letters required, each letter above or under results in a +5 byte penalty.
- If the number of words you've used is between 7 and 12, no penalty is incurred.

  - IF it exceeds 12, add 10 bytes per additional word.
  - IF it is less than 7, subtract 5 per missing word.

## Rules

- You may use any word from [the provided dictionary](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength/blob/master/unsorted.txt).
- Each word you output must be distinctively separated by either a space or a newline.
- Once a word combination has been posted, you may not use more than 6 of that answer's words together in a new answer.

  - This will be enforced by post date.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[word-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem)[kolmognogniznornia-complexitylty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmognogniznornia-complexitylty)
- Your score will be as defined in the scoring section.

Comment: How can you get a meaningful penalty for going under the number of letters required when `you must have AT LEAST the count above of each letter`?

Comment: Also, who was Kolmognogniznornia?

Comment: @JonathanFrech he was the first Aztec man to invent the concept of speech.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]: by design, a good answer will be incompressible. However, finding a good answer is going to involve a heavy computer search, and then the posted answer is going to be a string literal. That seems completely backwards: the interesting code should be what the question asks for.

Comment: @PeterTaylor was kinda going for something more unique, y'know? Sorta like my "5 favorite letters" challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Create a `.pdf` file

Your task is, given a non-empty string, to create a valid [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) (also see [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) for more information about the structure of PDF-files) file that contains no more than this string (no page numbers, date etc). Your submission has can either be a function or full program that achieves this task.

### Rules

- The input will be a **non-empty** string of [printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) ASCII characters, additionally the characters `\n` & `\t` may be part of the input but not the last character
- Your program/function produces a valid PDF file that contains that string but no more
- The representation of the string doesn't matter, except that it has to be a different color than the background, meaning valid representations may be (not limited to):

  - green text on black background (or the other way around)
  - the font is irrelevant but has to be consistent (it has to be readable without using a loupe)
  - some sort of image that represents the string
- The output has to be case sensitive
- If the string doesn't fit page width it needs to be split in a consistent manner such that it fits onto multiple lines (this means each character needs to be visible)
- If the lines don't fit onto a single page, you'll need to insert pagebreaks
- The width of a `\t` and  (space) need to be visibly different (`\t` larger)
- The PDF may contain one trailing empty page
- The PDF can be printed to STDOUT (ie. `call_your_program > test.pdf` would result in a valid PDF) or create a new file somewhere on your filesystem (the filename doesn't need to end in `.pdf` or `.PDF`)

### Example inputs

#### Valid

Printable string:

```
Hello, World!
```

Printable string containing newline(s):

```
Foo\nBar
```

Printable string containing newlines & horizontal tabs:

```
Line 1:\t!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\nLine 2:\t@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_\nLine 3:\t`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

#### Invalid

Trailing newline:

```
Hello, World!\n
```

Carriage return:

```
Foo\r\nBar
```

Empty string:

### Sandbox

Tags will be: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode), [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

- Are there other relevant tags?
- Is the challenge specific enough (creating PDFs that only work in an exotic PDF-reader etc)?

  - Should I limit the question such that the file has to be "viewable" in (for example) `xpdf`?
  - If so, would `xpdf` be a good choice?
- Is "readable" well defined enough (for example some people may claim that they are able to read [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) or even worse Comic Sans :P)
- Should I enforce a certain font size? What about even enforcing a certain font itself? (I feel this takes away too much freedom)
- Should I limit input such that it always fits onto a single page? (Loophole: people could choose a font size such that the input can only be one letter)

Comment: Is there a publicly available spec of the format, that doesn't require six months of waiting, 100$, signing a non-disclosure agreement and sacrificing a goat? If yes, do link. If not, I'm going to nope out of the challenge.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I'm looking for a solution for this issue, but it seems like without changing the file-format there's no way around this :( What a shame.. Also the pricing seems dynamic, are you referring to [this](https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html)? Because for me it shows nearly 200$ O.O

Comment: Oh boy. It seems I tried to overshoot the price by a comfortable margin and failed miserably.

Comment: This is ridiculous.. I expected the specs for PDF to be free since it is such a wide-spread format. Do you have a suggestion to resolve this issue apart from deleting this challenge?

Comment: You could go with a different format. OpenDocumentFormat is just a bunch of well documented XMLs packaged in a single ZIP file. Golfers can then try and see how much they can bend the rules before OpenOffice starts whining. Plus, zip files can technically be created without a library - just stick a mostly constant header before the uncompressed data.

Comment: I think http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf is publicly available, but I don't think this question's spec is quite clear enough. In particular, it should address line wrapping when the input text *doesn't* include newlines.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, yep that's public :) Thanks a lot! I'll see how I can address the line wrapping issue in a sensible manner (either by removing the `\n`s in the input or by creating a rule such that they can't just be ignored).

Comment: My main concern there is that it would be easy to just blit the text without caring whether it goes outside the page and is effectively lost.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good call! I updated the post, feel free edit in any suggestions or clarifications (this goes for anyone! If I'm not happy with it I can always revert).

Answer (score 1):

## Can You Catch the Robber?

This is not a cops and robbers type challenge, but a code-golf challenge based on the PBS Infinite Series video [Cops and Robbers Theorem](https://youtu.be/9mJEu-j1KT0).

### Challenge

You will be given an undirected and connected graph.  You may also assume the graph contains no self-loops; that is, the graph will not contain a vertex with an edge connecting to itself.  You must determine if the graph is cop-win.  That means that if a cop and robber start at any vertex, the cop will eventually land on the same vertex as the robber, with the cop and robber taking turns traversing one edge at a time, starting with the cop.  Both the cop and the robber are playing optimally and have the option to not move on their turn.

If you haven't watched the video, let me explain how to simplify the problem.  First, let's start with a definition.  A pitfall is any vertex `v` whose neighbors are all a distance of 0 or 1 from a common vertex `w`, where `v` is not equal to `w`.  To determine if a graph is cop-win, you must repeatedly remove pitfalls and the edges that connect to it until the graph is reduced to a single vertex or there are no more pitfalls to remove.  If the graph can be reduced to a single vertex in this way, it is cop-win.  A couple visual examples follow.

#### Example 1

```
>o---o---o
  \ / \ /
   o---o
    \ /
     o

  o---o<
 / \ /
o---o
 \ /
  o

 >o
 / \
o---o
 \ /
  o

>o---o
  \ /
   o

 >o
 /
o

o
```

**Result:** Cop-win

#### Example 2

```
  o---o---o<
 /     \   \
o---o   o---o
 \   \ /   /
  o---o---o

  o---o
 /     \
o---o   o---o
 \   \ /   /
  o---o---o<

  o---o
 /     \
o---o<  o---o
 \   \ /
  o---o

  o---o
 /     \
o       o---o<
 \     /
  o---o

  o---o
 /     \
o       o
 \     /
  o---o
```

**Result:** Not cop-win

### Examples

**Input:** `[[2,3],[2,4],[0,1,3,4,6],[0,2,5,6,8],[1,2,6,7,9],[3,8],[2,3,4,8,9,10],[4,9],[3,5,6,10],[4,6,7,10,11],[6,8,9,11],[9,10]]`
**Output:** Truthy

**Input:** `[[3],[4],[5],[0,5,6],[1,6],[2,3,7],[3,4,8],[5,9],[6,9,10],[7,8,11],[8],[9,12],[11]]`
**Output:** Falsy

**Input:** `[[1,2],[0,3],[0,3],[1,2]]`
**Output:** Falsy

**Input:** `[[1,2,3],[0,2,3],[0,1,3],[0,1,2]]`
**Output:** Truthy

### Rules

You may take input as an adjacency list, adjacency matrix, or list of edges, whose vertices may be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.  Your output must be a truthy or falsy value.  This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the least number of bytes in each language wins.

#### Notes

This is my first post; I could certainly benefit from some help in formulating and polishing my challenge.  If anyone believes my language was ambiguous or contradictory to what was said in the video, please help me clarify.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Comment: What is the input here? It looks a list of each vertex's neighbors, but could you clarify?

Comment: Yes that's what I was going for, an adjacency list.  A map of each vertex to a list of its neighbors.

Comment: This looks like a good question: meaty enough that there's something to golf, but simple enough not to scare everyone away. What I would suggest is flexibility in the input: allow people to choose whether to take input as adjacency matrix, adjacency list in the format you've used for the test cases, or list of edges. Also, allow people to use 1-indexed vertices rather than 0-indexed if they prefer.

Comment: I definitely agree with your suggestion of input leniency.  I'll update the challenge.

Comment: I'd suggest explaining what a cop-win graph is in full, including the start positions and that both players play an optimal strategy. A link to a non-video explanation would also be good for anyone who can't or doesn't want to watch a video.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @xnor.  I've worked it into the challenge.  I feel it's an improvement.  I think that the visual examples take up too much vertical space, so I'm not sure if I should include them or not.

Comment: IIRC it shouldn't be "start at any vertex", but the selection of the start position is part of the game, also under condition of optimal play, with the cop selecting their position first.

Answer (score 1):

## Number of all hyperrectangle-filling walks

**Your input:**

- size of the hyperrectangle – generally an *n*-tuple

  - eg. `(s,s)` in case of a square
- position in the hyperrectangle – generally **`0 <= pos[i] < size[i]`** for *i*-th dimension

  - eg. `(x,y)` where `0 <= x < s` and `0 <= y < s` in case of a `(s,s)` square.

**Your task:** Find the number of walks in the hyperrectangle, which start at the given position and visit each cell of the hyperrectangle exactly once.

In the context of this task, a **walk is a sequence of positions**, such that each position after the first differs from the previous one in exactly one dimension by amount of exactly `1`. Eg. in the case of a 2x2 square, a possible walk would be `(0,0) -> (0,1) -> (1,1) -> (1,0)`.

**Note:** It doesn't matter whether `x` is vertical position and `y` horizontal or vice versa. Neither it matters whether coordinates grow downwards / upwards or to the left / right (eg. vertical axis might grow downwards or upwards without any effect on the result). These statements extend to higher dimensions as well.

***Related task:*** [Longest hypercube path](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144118/longest-hypercube-path)

### Example

Given `size = (3,3)` and `pos = (0,0)`, there are 8 solutions. These can be divided into four equivalence classes under the relation of transposition, viz. `A == Transpose(A)`. Only one solution for each equivalence class needs to be found, the other one can be obtained by simply transposing the first one.

The four "canonical" solutions:
[image: (3,3);(0,0) Canonical solutions]

**Output:** `8`.

### Possible specializations

**Specialization 1:** Support only hypercubes (hyperrectangles with equal sizes in each dimension).
**Specialization 2:** Support only 2-dimensional hypercubes (squares).

### My questions

1. (Obvious question) Has this task already been presented?
2. Is this task (in its general form) too difficult? Would it be more reasonable to restrict it to one of the specializations (or to a different specialization)?

Comment: Have you made a reference implementation? It seems to me that it would be worth generating some sequences for the two specialisations and seeing whether they're in OEIS, and whether closed forms for the answers and known.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Those were my thoughts, but I haven't yet gotten around to making an implementation. I suspect the sequences for specializations (especially Spec. 2) will be in OEIS and most likely will have a closed-form solution, but it's in the higher dimensions where it gets interesting, especially if you consider optimizations based on symmetries.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have written a (hopefully correct) [implementation in Python 2](https://goo.gl/FaWffg); though it being a brute-force algorithm, higher dimensional hypercuboids may require some time to be examined...

Comment: The relevant OEIS sequence for a hypercube of side lengths `2`, starting at one corner, is [A003043](http://oeis.org/A003043).

Comment: I for one really like this challenge and do not think any _specialization_ which makes the task easier is required.

Answer (score 1):

## Is it Odd or Even

A group is an "Odd or Even group" if there is some member **a** such that every member in the group can be represented as either **k • k** or **k • k • a**.

For example the group **Z<sub>4</sub>** is an even odd group if **a = 1**

```
0 = 2 • 2             Even
1 = 2 • 2 • 1         Odd
2 = 1 • 1             Even
3 = 1 • 1 • 1         Odd
```

The even and odd members can overlap, for example in **Z<sub>5</sub>** if **a =1** every member is both even and odd.

```
0 = 0 • 0 = 2 • 2 • 1 Even and Odd
1 = 3 • 3 = 0 • 0 • 1 Even and Odd
2 = 1 • 1 = 3 • 3 • 1 Even and Odd
3 = 4 • 4 = 1 • 1 • 1 Even and Odd
4 = 2 • 2 = 4 • 4 • 1 Even and Odd
```

An example of a group that is not an Even or Odd group is the Klein-4 group (**Z<sub>2</sub>×Z<sub>2</sub>**), because **k + k = 0** for all **k** meaning there can be only one even member and one odd member despite there being 4 members of the group.

### Task

Given the Cayley table of a finite group determine if it is a Odd or Even group.  You will be guaranteed that the input is a group, but you will not be guaranteed anything else.  This is a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) so your code should output two distinct values one for accept and one for reject.

Answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Test cases

#### True

```
0 1
1 0

0 1 2 3
1 2 3 0
2 3 0 1
3 0 1 2

0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 0
2 3 4 0 1
3 4 0 1 2
4 0 1 2 3

0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 4 5 2 3
2 5 0 4 3 1
3 4 5 0 1 2
4 3 1 2 5 0
5 2 3 1 0 4
```

#### False

```
0 1 2 3
1 0 3 2
2 3 0 1
3 2 1 0

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 0 5 6 7 4
2 3 0 1 6 7 4 5
3 0 1 2 7 4 5 6
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
5 6 7 4 1 2 3 0
6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1
7 4 5 6 3 0 1 2
```

Comment: The first paragraph is difficult to understand: It is not very clear that you define the terms "even" and "odd" and that the definition is dependent on `a`.  Furthermore you first talk about numbers, but then talk about members of a group, so I'd avoid mentioning *numbers*, and perhaps link the wikipedia page about groups. The additive notation suggests you're only considering abelian groups, is that true? I'd also define first `Z_n` as the cyclic group of order n.

Comment: Next question: The definition of "even" and "odd" seems to depend on `a`, so what is `a` then in your test cases?

Comment: @flawr I'll try to clean up the first bit but addressing your second question.  In the truthy examples **a** can be any member of the following sets `{1}`, `{1,3}`, `{0,1,2,3,4}`, `{1,2,3}` (same order as examples).

Comment: @flawr Is that a better explanation?

Comment: Yes now it is a lot clearer! One question remains, do you only consider abelian groups?

Comment: @flawr No, the 4th test case is the dihedral 6 group which is not commutative.

Comment: In that case you'd probably be better off using multiplicative notation and explicitly saying that it is possible that the operation is noncommutative.

Comment: I think you should add some more explanation about the input, without some knowledge of group theory one cannot understand what is a Cayley table or what to do with it. (You use just $Z4$ or $Z5$ in your explanation, but then there are tables in the test cases, which is confusing)

Comment: Could use a test case where the number of distinct squares is at least half the size of the group but the group is not odd or even.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd rather not.  The test cases are already much larger than the rest of the question, and there are not a lot of falsy cases.  If there is such a case then it would be enormous.

Answer (score 1):

## Evaluate a Starting Position in a Partitioning Game

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

Two players play a partitioning game.  At the start of the game, there are `n` stones, all in a single heap.  When a player takes a turn, they must divide an existing heap into two, ensuring that every heap still has a distinct size.  The game is over when a player has no legal moves; that player loses.

For example, suppose that Max and Min are playing with `n=6`.  Initially it is Max's turn, and he divides the starting heap into a heap of size one and a heap of size five.  Min then divides the heap of size five into heaps of size two and three (her only option because she cannot make another heap of size one).  Max, seeing heaps of size one, two, and three, has no legal move and loses.

Alternatively, Max could have split the size-six heap into heaps of size two and four.  But then Min could not split the heap of size two (she would end up with both new heaps having size one), nor could she split the heap of size four evenly (for the same reason), so she would be forced to split the heap of size four into heaps of size one and three.  Max would have lost anyway.

Since Max, the player to move first, has no winning strategy at `n=6`, call six a **losing number**.  Similarly, call values of `n` for which Max can win (at least if he plays cleverly) **winning numbers**.  Max wants a way to distinguish winning and losing numbers for his upcoming rematch against Min.

Write a program or function that, given an `n`, returns or outputs one value for losing numbers and a distinct value for winning numbers.  For testing purposes, the first 50 winning numbers are:

```
3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 78, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93
```

(This sequence is related to, but distinct from [A161983](https://oeis.org/A161983).)

Rules and scoring are as usual for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).  The checkmark will go to an answer with well-explained and/or especially clever golfing, even if it doesn't compete with terser languages.

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a program to output a string in yup

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

yup is an older language of mine with the following commands:

```
0   Pushes 0 to the stack.
e   Takes an argument N and pushes exp(N).
|   Takes an argument N and pushes ln(N).
~   Switches top two items on stack.
:   Duplicates the top item on the stack.
-   Subtracts the top of stack from the second-to-top of stack.
{   Begin while loop (while top of stack is positive and is defined).
}   End while loop.
$   Reverse the stack.
[   Moves the bottom of the stack to the top of the stack.
]   Moves the top of the stack to the bottom of the stack.
*   Pushes an input item (char/number) to the stack.
\   Terminates the program.
@   Outputs top of stack as a character. (When used on a non-int, rounds the real portion.)
#   Outputs top of stack as a number.
```

For example, the program `00e` pushes `0`, then `0`, then pops a `0`, pushing `exp(0)`, yielding the stack `[0, 1]`.

### Rules

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is to create a program that, when given a string, outputs a short yup program that would output the given string. **Your score is determined by the total number of bytes used to generate all test cases below.**

### Test cases

Formatted as a .JSON file (array of strings):

```
["Hello, World!", " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz", "", "[[<<>>]]", "adksjf 9823-0 =-ao0sdf';zlx", "b662bf6c7a7cac66561025cf2509506f", "yup", " ~!}", "death surely will find us all", "NO_ONE_IS_HERE", "Ra Ra Rasputin", "hello\nWORLD", "*0e-{0e-}#", "            ", "go play nethack", "\ttabs\n vs spaces\r\n", ".", "~", "it is not necessarily unfair that we can single-handedly close challenges, --MrXcoder", "\nconst math = require(\"mathjs\");\nconst escape = require(\"escape-string-regexp\");\nconst Stack = require(\"./stack.js\");\nconst entries = require(\"./entries.js\");", "Never gonna give you up\nNever gonna let you down\nNever gonna turn around\nAnd outgolf you", "010100101000001000100111101010", "O0O0O0OOOO00O000O0OOOO0O00O0", "[0, [1, [2, 3], 4], 5]", "(()()()))))(()()))"]
```

If I feel submissions too heavily optimize for the given inputs, I will use a second set of words, with an md5hash of `30272eee598205bab2904e9768502517`.

Comment: Will you use the second set of words for all submission or only the one you feel like it's optimized? Also why not just combine both sets in any case?

Comment: @BruceForte Once I feel that there are optimized answers, I will use the second list. (It's really just a variation of the first list with changed characters and similar, to ensure optimizing some constants but not others is prohibited)

Answer (score 1):

## Insertion sort counter

Calculate the number of moves necessary to do an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) of an input vector containing positive integers.

Insertion sort iterates, consuming one input element each repetition, and growing a sorted output list. At each iteration, insertion sort removes one element from the input data, finds the location it belongs within the sorted list, and inserts it there. It repeats until no input elements remain.

You must count the number of times a number is moved from its original position. For instance, the vector `[1,2,3,4]` requires no moves, as it's already sorted, while the vector `[1,3,4,2]` requires one move, since  the last `2` must be moved two places to the left.

#### Example:

```
Input: 
[6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]
Sorting:
0: [6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]
1: [5, 6, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]
2: [3, 5, 6, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]
3: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 2, 4]
4: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4]
5: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4]
6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Output: 6
```

#### Test cases:

To be added!

Comment: You should describe what an insertion sort is, for those who don't know.

Comment: Will do :) Thanks.

Comment: As defined, the answer is always `len(input)`. I've no idea what the example is supposed to show (or how it's counting).

Comment: @PeterTaylor The number of insertions (maybe I should call it moves, or something else?) necessary for the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is zero. The number of moves for the array `[1, 3, 4, 2]` is one, since the only number that must be moved when using the insertion sort algorithm is the last `2`, that must be moved two steps to the left, resulting in a sorted array. Placing a number back in its original position doesn't count as an insertion/move. Does that make sense?

Comment: So "*Count the number of array elements `a[i]` which are not the greatest element in `a[:i+1]`*"?

Comment: I guess that's another way to put it, yes...

Comment: Maybe you could have it count the number of swaps assuming that you can only move a number by swapping it with one of its neighbors (and many implementations of insertion sort actually do this, especially those operating on arrays). For example, the number of moves for [1,3,4,2] would be 2, because the number `2` must be shifted twice to the left.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. Thanks! :) I'll probably change it when I get the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

## The XOR Quines!

Your challenge is to make a program that outputs its source code but when each of its bytes are XORed with its answer number, it outputs the source code of the previous program.

For example, if the previous program was:

```
print 1
```

and your program is number #2, than your program could be this:

```
cngpv*%rpklv"3%+
```

which outputs in your language:

```
cngpv*%rpklv"3%+
```

and when each byte is XORed with 2, you get:

```
alert('print 1')
```

which outputs the previous program:

```
print 1
```

Note that the first program doesn't have to do anything other than output its own source code.

The second-to last answer after a month of no answers posted wins.

Comment: This is going to be too hardcore.

Comment: This is going to be *way* too hard except in certain esolangs. Since every answer builds off of the previous one, they are probably going to get bigger. I would recommend starting with a simple esolang that ignores most characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Tear Down that Wall

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

[Related (dupe?)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144600/hide-the-needle-in-the-haystack-cops)

- This is my first time submitting a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.
- Suggestions and constructive criticism are always welcome.

#### Cops:

As the cop, your task is to create a code that outputs this ASCII wall:

```
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

However, by ***deleting*** some part(s) of the code, it must also output a broken wall:

```
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___                    |___|___|
___|___|_                    __|___|__
_|___|___                    |___|___|
___|___|_                    __|___|__
_|___|___                    |___|___|
___|___|_                    __|___|__
_|___|___                    |___|___|
___|___|_                    __|___|__
_|___|___                    |___|___|
___|___|_                    __|___|__
```

### Rules:

1. Your code **must** terminate in a reasonable amount of time as long as it's correct. That means that the whole code and the correctly broken code **must** output the wall (broken or not) within 60 (too much or too little time? sugestions?) seconds. That doesn't apply if the code is incorrectly broken by the robber.
2. The broken wall needs to be output(ted? English is hard) **without addition of code**.
3. You may obfuscate the code as much as you see fit. (does hashing/encrypting count as obfuscating? if so, should it be allowed?)
4. You **must** state what language you used in your answer.
5. Your wall will be safe if, after 1 week, it hasn't been broken. You **must** also reveal the answer. Your wall will **not** be safe until you have revealed the answer.
6. The outputs must match the exact ASCII walls provided. Leading/trailing newlines are allowed as long as the output matches the one provided. The walls consist of 13 lines and 38 columns of the characters `|` and `_`. The broken section of the wall is a block of 20 whitespace characters per line, beginning at the fourth line. The "padding" is of 9 characters (`|` or `_`) to either side of the whitespace block.
7. Preferably, include a link to an online interpreter for your chosen language.

(any other rules suggestions?)

#### Robbers:

As the robber, your task is to, well, break the wall!

### Rules:

1. You **may not add** any code to the answer, only **delete**.
2. The code is considered broken **if and only if** it outputs the **entire** broken wall.
3. The broken code **must** be a valid submission in the same language as the original code.
4. Please include in your answer a link to the answer you cracked and which part(s) of the code you modified.

## Sandbox:

- Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide the Needle in the Haystack (Cops)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144600/41024) and [Find the Needle in the Haystack (Robbers)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144601/41024).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Added to the post as a possible duplicate.

Comment: Definitely a dupe, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## Does the Riemann hypothesis hold?

[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

I would like to earn a million dollars, and [the hardest way to do it](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-hardest-way-to-make-a-million-dollars) is apparently solving one of the Millenium problems, so let's focus on one: the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis).

Now, how could I possibly ever solve it? By writing a computer program, of course! However, I am lazy, so I would rather have you do the work for me by making the program as short as possible (to minimize the number of key strokes required for me to verify your results)

### The challenge

Your goal is to write a program in a language of your choice which would decide the Riemann hypothesis. More precisely, you should write a program which terminates iff the Riemann hypothesis fails.

### Restrictions

- **The program has to work when running with empty input** [Sandbox note: perhaps allow input but add it to byte count?]
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Your program must **provably** terminate iff RH is false. For example, submitting two programs, one trivially terminating, one trivially not terminating, and claiming one of them works, is not allowed, since neither of the programs *provably* works.
- You must give a proof of equivalence of your program's termination with RH failing, with references to other work allowed. I give myself the right to decide whether the work referenced is valid or not, to exclude the [many proofs and disproofs of RH](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/RHproofs.htm).
- If the Riemann hypothesis doesn't hold, your program can throw an error, or simply exit, as long as the program cannot continue beyond that.
- You may assume you have unlimited memory and time, and also that your number types can hold real numbers of arbitrary size to arbitrary precision.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Sandbox comment

To address the comments below, let me clarify why this challenge is most definitely solvable. Note that the problem is *not* of the sort "give a counterexample to RH" (if it did, then it would fall under [this discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11033/49734) and I completely agree it would not be a good challenge). Instead, it asks for a program whose termination depends on RH, and then one can give valid solutions regardless of the fact that RH is not solved yet.

To give an analogy (following Deedlit's example), suppose we have replaced RH with Goldbach's conjecture. This conjecture surely is unresolved, but one can give a valid solution to the challenge, for example by following this pseudocode:

```
n = 4
while true:
 found = false
 for k from 1 to n-1:
  if k is prime and n-k is prime:
   found = true
   break
 if found == false:
  break
 else:
  n = n+2
return 0
```

If Goldbach's conjecture is false, this program will eventually terminate by returning 0 (namely, when it finds the first counterexample). Otherwise, it will stay in the while loop forever. Hence it would be a valid solution.

My challenge as it stands can be solved in a similar manner, perhaps using

> one of the many known [equivalents of RH](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39944/collection-of-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis).

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11033/45941

Comment: @Mego My proposed challenge doesn't fall under that discussion. It is not an open problem whether a solution for that problem is possible.

Comment: Relying on open problems for challenges is not a good idea. Either it will be impossible to answer because the problem isn't solved, or answers will be trivial copy jobs of the proof once the problem is solved. This challenge relies on both an open problem (Riemann hypothesis) and an unsolvable problem (halting problem).

Comment: @Mego The way I have phrased my problem makes it possible, but not trivial, once the Riemann hypothesis is unsolved. True, the problem trivializes once we get a (dis)proof of RH, but until then I don't see an issue with this problem. Also, I don't see how halting problem is in any way relevant here.

Comment: You don't see how the halting problem is relevant in a challenge for writing problems that halt iff some unsolved problem in mathematics is true?

Comment: @Mego Let me rephrase - I don't see how its unsolvability impacts the challenge in any way.

Comment: @Mego As an example, it is straightforward to write a program that halts if and only if the Goldbach conjecture is false. Simply test out even numbers one at a time until you find one that is not the sum of two prime numbers. The unsolvability of the halting problem doesn't have any bearing on this, since we aren't relying on an algorithm that determines the halting behavior of _all_ programs. A program that halts precisely when the Riemann Hypothesis is true could be done similarly.

Comment: @Deedlit Can one also show that it is possible to write a program that halts iff Goldbach's conjecture is true?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I believe that's an open problem. However, thanks to your comment I've realized I have mixed things up - my challenge should've been about RH being _false_, not true (so just like in Deedlit's example with Goldbach). Sorry if any confusion was caused.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, that seems solvable then. Would one, however, not simply loop through all complex numbers (as one has a lot of computational power), implement the zeta function (again, infinite computational power) and halt if they find a counterexample to the hypothesis?

Comment: @JonathanFrech It needs to be quite a bit more than that, because there are uncountably many complex numbers, so you can't loop over them all even with unbounded computing power. I believe you can do it by evaluating a contour integral around rectangles in the complex plane and looping over these rectangles. And it gets annoying around the critical line. It's definitely more complicated than just implementing the zeta function, though.

Comment: @Chris Could one not loop through all possible sums of all rationals to approximate the reals, argue that every real is computable by an infinite sum of rationals, do that twice to gain a program which theoretically looks at every complex number, implement the zeta function and check if the hypothesis holds?

Comment: @JonathanFrech It's not possible to look at all possible infinite sums of rational numbers. Some (in fact, most) are uncomputable, and either way there are just _too many_ real/complex numbers. Try to implement your algorithm in a real language like C, you will see that this simply doesn't go through.

Comment: @Wojowu Do I not have unlimited computational time?

Comment: @JonathanFrech You do, but either way you can only do countably many operations; the set of complex numbers is _not_ countable.

Comment: @Wojowu Okay, sorry, it did not occur to me that your infinite operations have to be countable. Since there is not mapping from a countably infinite set to an uncountably infinite one, however, could one not argue that this task is impossible or am I missing something?

Comment: @JonathanFrech It is not possible to cycle through all possible complex numbers, but there are other ways which would let one verify the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @Wojowu Rather, there are other ways one could refute the Riemann hypothesis, right? As far as I know, there's no known algorithm that halts iff the Riemann hypothesis is true.

Comment: @Chris err, yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

## Square-free Rock-Paper-Scissors tournament

On the day of the Codegolf *Rock-Paper-Scissors tournament* you hear through the grapevine that everybody else is going to play a fix *square-free* sequence (a sequence made of the letters `R`, `P`, `S` is square-free if it does not contain a subsequence that repeats twice. See [Don't repeat yourself in Rock-Paper-Scissors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146675/dont-repeat-yourself-in-rock-paper-scissors) for details.)

### Task

Write a program that for a game of `N` rounds, in each round `n`

1. prints one of `R`, `P`, `S` - its own `n`th hand (using all information gained so far)
2. receives an input of either `R`, `P`, `S` - the `n`th letter of the opponent's sequence

### Rules

- Rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, paper beats rock.
- The "opponents" are all the square-free sequences of the given length.
- Your program may read the opponents moves at once and print its own moves - as long as it is functionally equivalent to a program reading the moves in the order specified in section "task".
- The program does not carry a state between playing against different opponents.
- Each entry should include a scoring script computing the score of the candidate against all square-free sequences of length `N`.

### Scoring

I am posting this to get some input about interesting scoring methods and a good choice of `N`.

Programs should score high if they *win* against a large fraction of square free sequences in an economic way. A possible criterium of "winning" against a single sequence is winning more hands against an opponent than losing.
A possible criterium of scoring high is number of games won divided by the root of bytes.

Comment: I'd say 16 could be a good choice for N, this would give 798 different opponents, which are still a manageable amount, and each game would probably be long enough to make the square-free analisys matter

Comment: To win with a small margin it is enough to exploit that the sequence does not repeat. I think we need to put the winning margin into the score or put a threshold.

Comment: Maybe (rounds won - rounds lost)/bytes^2 , where rounds are counted from all the matches together

Answer (score 1):

## Polynomial Partition

**META**: Right now I'm wondering whether it would be a more interesting challenge to have two imput lists, and the program just needs to find a polynomial that separates the two lists (i.e. no connected component can contain points of *both* classes. Or altnernatively `f(x,y)>0` for all `(x,y)` in list `A`, and `f(x,y)<0` for all `(x,y)` in list `B`.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions)[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Given a finite list of at at least two points in the plane `ℝ²` (all points in the list are unique), your program should find a polynomial `f` in `ℝ[x,y]` whose zero locus `Z(f) := {(x,y) ∊ ℝ² | f(x,y) = 0}` partitions the plane such that each of the connected components of `ℝ²\Z(f)` contains at most one point of the input list. The goal is finding such an `f` of a low degree. (It does not have to be optimal.) Note that no point of the input list may be contained in `Z(f)`.

#### Scoring

The score for each test cases is the degree of the polynomial that your algorithm produces. The total score is the product of the scores of the testcases.

#### Examples

The points `{(0,0),(0,2)}` can be separated by `f(x,y) = y - 1` (degree 1) or `f(x,y) = x² + y² - 1` (degree 2) or `f(x,y) = x³ + 1 - y`(degree 3) or (infinitely) many more.

The points `{(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)}` can be separated by `f(x,y) = xy` (degree 2).

#### Test Battery

to be included...

Comment: (1) I presume that the words "*a different*" are missing from "*each of the inputs is in ^one of the connected components*". (2) Is the optimal solution not going to be one of the easiest approaches?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I rewrote (1), regarding (2): One very easy not optimal solution would be making a a small enough circle around every point, so I guess it depends.

Answer (score 1):

## Palindromic Collapse

Given a string `s`, traverse from left-to-right, finding the first prefix that is a palindrome. When you encounter the first prefix palindrome, remove the end-half of the palindrome. Insert it back into the original string, then restart again from the left side of the new word. Return the final result when no prefixes are palindromes.

Take for example "babble":

- First check would be `[ba]bble`, which is not a palindrome, move on.
- Second check would be `[bab]ble`, which is a palindrome (`bab`).

  1. Compress the palindrome to the first "half", `[bab]` becomes `[ba]`.
  2. Reattach this in place of the original palindrome, resulting in `[ba]ble`
- Next we repeat, finding `[bab]le` again, and resulting in  `[ba]le` after steps 1 and 2.
- We then iterate through the full word again, finding no palindromes, returning `bale`.

---

## More Examples (worked out)

**moom**

```
[mo]om (not a palindrome)
[moo]m (nont a palindrome)
[moom] (palindrome) -> [mo]
[mo]   (not a palindrome, done).
```

**Final returned result: `mo`**

---

**abalbalba**

```
[ab]albalba (not a palindrome)
[aba]lbalba (palindrome) -> [ab]lbalba
[ab]lbalba  (not a palindrome)
[abl]balba  (not a palindrome)
[ablb]alba  (not a palindrome)
[ablba]lba  (palindrome) -> [abl]lba
[ab]llba    (not a palindrome)
[abl]lba    (not a palindrome)
[abll]ba    (not a palindrome)
[abllb]a    (not a palindrome)
[abllba]    (palindrome) -> [abl]
[ab]l       (not a palindrome)
[abl]       (not a palindrome, done)
```

**Final returned result: `abl`**

---

## More 1-1 Examples

```
amanaplanacanalpanama -> amnaplanacanalpanama
1232132121            -> 123
1232132145            -> 12345
01001000123210        -> 01123210
01000000000000000001  -> 011
010101                -> 011
abbabababaa           -> ab
hellollehworld        -> helloworld
world                 -> world
<empty string>        -> <empty string>
```

Comment: You like [tag:palindrome] a lot, don't you?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder in all fairness it looks like Oliver Ni likes them more.

Answer (score 1):

## Validate a StarCraft II Build Order

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

## Explanation

You must decide whether the input represents a valid StarCraft II Build Order. Here is how you will decide:

1. Start with the first word (it will be the race, `Zerg`, `Protoss`, or `Terran`)
2. Set the list of *valid* units to just the ones from that race (explained later)
3. Loop through the input (split by space)

   1. Check if the unit is in the list of valid items for the listed race

      - Otherwise, output `Invalid item` + the listed item's name
   2. Check that the player has enough supply to sustain that unit (if it's a unit) (explained later)
   3. Check that the player has the prerequisites for that item

## Units and Structures

(will be listed in real question)

Example:

Terran:

- `CommandCenter` `0` supply, requires `SCV` gives `+15` supply
- `OrbitalCommand` `0` supply, requires `CommandCenter` (consumes)

Zerg:

- `Hatchery` `-1` supply, requires `Drone` (consumes) gives `+6` supply
- `Drone` `1` supply, requires `Hatchery`
- `SpawningPool` `-1` supply, requires `Hatchery`, `Drone` (consumes)

Protoss:

- `Nexus` `0` supply, requires `Probe` gives `+15` supply

## StarCraft II Mechanics

At the beginning of the game, the player starts with a town hall (`Nexus`, `CommandCenter`, or `Hatchery` + `Overlord`) and `12` workers (`Probe`, `SCV`, or `Drone`).

Supply is the maximum number of units one can have. `Supply Depots`, `Pylons`, and `Overlords` give more supply.

The sum of the supply of all produced units can never exceed the current supply value (we ignore Zerg hacks).

The Supply cannot exceed `200`.

## Input

You will receive an input in any valid way in this format:

```
Race <item> <item> .....
```

There will be at most 99 items, and they will be at most 30 chars long.

The race will be one of `Zerg`, `Protoss`, or `Terran`.

Answer (score 1):

## Prune my tree

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Given a well-formed ASCII<sup>†</sup> art tree and the name of a node, print or return a new, well-formed tree with that node and any children removed.

†Contains non-ASCII characters.

### Example

Given this input tree:

```
A
├ B
├ C
│ └ D
└ E
```

...and the node name `E`, the following should be returned:

```
A
├ B
└ C
  └ D
```

### Well-formed trees

Rather than an exhaustive spec, I'll define well-formedness by example:

```
A
├ B
├ C
├ D
│ ├ E
│ └ F
├ G
│ └ H
│   ├ I
│   │ ├ J
│   │ └ K
│   └ L
└ M
  ├ N
  │ └ O
  │   └ P
  ├ Q
  └ R
```

The above is the only valid way to represent this tree (rules above re: trailing spaces and newline apply here and henceforth). Note that:

1. The tree is rendered with some strict subset of the characters `├`, `│`, `└`, `A`–`Z`, space, and newline.
2. The tree has one root node (in this example `A`) with no characters to its left or right.
3. Each line has exactly one node.
4. Each `└` and `├` is followed by a single space (required) and node name.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- This is an [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenge; input and output must be a string or array of lines or equivalent, per standard rules.
- Trailing spaces and/or a single trailing newline are allowed in both input and output.
- You may use any character encoding, as long your solution prints or returns characters equivalent to `├`, `│`, and `└`. (ASCII characters like `+`, `|` (pipe) and `L` (capital "l") are *not* equivalent.)

  See also "Freebies" under "Scoring" below.

#### Input

- The input tree will have at least one node.
- The given named node may or may not exist in the tree. If it does not exist, the original tree should be returned.
- Each node name will be a single character between `A` and `Z` inclusive. Node names will be unique and there will be no more than 26 nodes.
- Node names are *not* guaranteed to be contiguous nor in any particular order, e.g. the following is possible input:

  ```
  Q
  └ D
  ```

#### Output

- The output tree may have zero nodes.
- The order of the remaining nodes in the output tree must be the same as the input tree.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest solution in bytes wins.

**Freebies:** If the literal characters `├`, `│`, or `└` appear in your source code, you may count them as one byte each, per occurrence.

### Test cases

I'll reuse a few trees for multiple test cases.

1. Input tree:

   ```
   A
   ```

   - Output if `A` removed:
   - Output if `B` removed (`B` doesn't exist):

     ```
     A
     ```
2. Input tree:

   ```
   A
   ├ B
   ├ C
   │ └ D
   └ E
   ```

   - Output if `C` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     └ E
     ```
   - Output if `D` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     ├ C
     └ E
     ```
   - Output if `E` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     └ C
       └ D
     ```
3. Input tree:

   ```
   A
   ├ B
   ├ C
   ├ D
   │ ├ E
   │ └ F
   ├ G
   │ └ H
   │   ├ I
   │   │ ├ J
   │   │ └ K
   │   └ L
   └ M
     ├ N
     │ └ O
     │   └ P
     ├ Q
     └ R
   ```

   - Output if `H` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     ├ C
     ├ D
     │ ├ E
     │ └ F
     ├ G
     └ M
       ├ N
       │ └ O
       │   └ P
       ├ Q
       └ R
     ```
   - Output if `L` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     ├ C
     ├ D
     │ ├ E
     │ └ F
     ├ G
     │ └ H
     │   └ I
     │     ├ J
     │     └ K
     └ M
       ├ N
       │ └ O
       │   └ P
       ├ Q
       └ R
     ```
   - Output if `M` removed:

     ```
     A
     ├ B
     ├ C
     ├ D
     │ ├ E
     │ └ F
     └ G
       └ H
         ├ I
         │ ├ J
         │ └ K
         └ L
     ```

## Questions for sandbox:

1. Enough/too many/missing test cases?
2. Enough/too many/missing details re: input/output?

Comment: I would just make this an (actual) ASCII-art challenge. Up to you but meh

Comment: Given the proximity to Christmas, you could go for "trim the tree" as the title.

Comment: I think you should show the larger test case(s) with `A` removed. I know/guess it will be an empty output, but still, it's a corner case that will benefit from being properly shown.

Comment: I like the idea, but I too would prefer ASCII-only. Non-ascii adds a bunch of bytes without adding anything to the challenge itself.

Answer (score 1):

## Lines per file

Can't believe it was not questioned yet.

I want the shortest script you can supply to take on all files on a directory and output a list in the format

`file    number_of_lines`

Every possibility should be accounted as a valid line terminator:

```
- <CR>
- <LF>
- <CR><LF>
- <LF><CR>
```

No winner, it is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) per language basis. Still thinking if I should give some bonus for sorting by line count.

Comment: [Duplicate.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108403/find-the-smallest-file) Not the same but pretty much the same idea, would definitely get closed for dupeness.

Comment: @Riker: Counting lines requires some more effort than the file's byte size! I had even posted an answer on that question!

Comment: It's literally just `wc -l` to count lines.. I'm not sure about most of the others, but I know at least my bash can be trivially modified to count lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Shortest Path Distance

Uh oh! You want to get to the point (10,10) from the origin, but there are a whole bunch of boxes in the way! What is the length of the shortest path which avoids all of them?

### Input

Your program should take a set of rectangles, defined by the coordinates of two opposite corners, as input; the format is up to you.

For example, a possible input might look like

```
[[(1,3), (5,2)], [(5,4), (7,5)]]
```

But you could also take it as

```
[(1,3), (5,2)]
[(5,4), (7,5)]
```

Or anything else, as long as it allows for unambiguous input.

These inputs would define the rectangles shown below:
[image: Minimum path length to A from (0,0): sqrt(10) + sqrt(130), approx 14.564]

You can assume that all rectangles will have integer coordinates with x,y between 1 and 9 inclusive, which guarantees a possible path. You can also assume that no rectangles intersect in any way (that means no shared edges or vertexes).

### Output

Your program/function must return the value of the shortest path from the origin to (10,10), have the absolute error at most 10<sup>-2</sup> and measured using the euclidean metric.

In the example given above, 14.564 and 14.56 would be accepted, while 14.55 and 14.57 would not.

### Example I/O

```
[[(1,3), (5,2)], [(5,4), (7,5)]] -> 11.40
[] -> 14.14
[[(1,1), (2,9)], [(9,2), (3,1)]] -> 14.28
[[(2,2), (1,1)], [(9,3), (8,5)], [(1,9), (2,8)]] -> 14.28 (Note: rounded up)
[[(9,1), (1,9)]] -> 18.11
```

### Other Rules

Shortest code wins, no exploiting loopholes, yadda yadda yadda, you get the idea, it's code golf.

Comment: The taxicab (Manhattan) distance is always 20. I don't know Taxi PL, but I suppose it is not too hard to write.

Comment: @user202729 Not true in the case that backtracking is required.

Comment: Using taxicab distance instead of manhattan distance makes the challenge slightly easier and more accessible to languages that can't handle floating-point well.

Comment: @Challenger5 Why does output `20` require backtracking???

Comment: @user202729 If backtracking is required (e.g. the blocks form a spiral shape), then the taxicab distance will be >20.

Comment: @Challenger5 No, `all rectangles will have integer coordinates with x,y between 1 and 9 `, which means that you can always move `(0, 0) → (0, 10) → (10, 10)`, which have taxicab distance = 20.

Comment: Ready for posting to main?

Comment: Alternatively, you could ask not for the *length* of the shortest path but for the actual path!

Comment: @flawr ... Isn't that harder? I don't know...

Comment: @user202729 How else would you calculate the length of a shortest path if not by explicitly finding a shortest path?

Comment: What if we have two rectangles that touch eachother but do not share edges or vertices, like `[(0,0),(2,1)]` and `[(1,1),(3,2)]`? Also: Can we e.g. assume a certain representation of the rectangles (i.e. always first the top left vertex, then the bottom right)?

Comment: @flawr Unfortunately, it seems that the OP abandoned this... Also, Dijkstra algorithm. (it calculates the shortest distance from source to all points, so by triangle inequality you can deduce the path, but it definitely takes more code than just outputting the distance)

Answer (score 1):

## Smallest Proth Prime Power

A Proth Prime is a prime number of the form `(k*2^n)+1`.

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `k`, return the smallest non-negative integer `n` such that `(k*2^n)+1` is a prime.

This is code-golf, so smallest answer in bytes will win!

[OEIS link for this sequence](http://oeis.org/A040076)

[OEIS link for sequence shifted by 1, with alternative calculation method](http://oeis.org/A225721)

### Test cases:

```
Input Output
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     0
7     2
8     1
9     1
10    0
11    1
12    0
13    2
14    1
15    1
16    0
17    3
18    0
19    6
20    1
46    0
47    583
48    1
```

---

#### TODO:

- Rework preamble
- More/better test cases?

Answer (score 1):

## Packing Density of Polyline Defined Shapes

So... I was making bacon this morning and I couldn't fit all of my bacon into my pan. However I oriented the strips, there was always one or two pieces that didn't fit. Culinary endeavors aside, here's my challenge:

### Input:

pan and bacon

Each of these inputs is a list of (X,Y) coordinates that define a closed shape. The very first index and the very last index are different, but the shape is closed. It not guaranteed that the shape is convex, but it is guaranteed that the path doesn't cross itself. Further, for simplicity, you may expect all the (x,y) coordinates to be integers.

Your program must find the most occurences of bacon that can fit into the pan, allowing rotation and flipping.

### Output:

An integer that represents how much bacon can fit in the pan.

### Scoring and rules:

For proper cooking:

- A `bacon` may touch another `bacon` or the edge of the `pan`.
- `bacon` may not overlap, nor may it go off the `pan`.
- The first index of both `pan` and `bacon` is *always* (0,0).
- If there is a tie in number of bytes, the user whose code is formatted to look like ASCII bacon wins.
- If two users tie and both have ascii bacon, upvotes wins. 
  Standard rules apply. This is code golf, so the standard rules apply.

## Sample input and output:

### Test Case 1:

*`Bacon` directly overlaps the pan, and is the same size.*

`pan`:  [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
`bacon`: [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
Output: 1

### Test Case 2:

*When `bacon` is bigger than `pan`*

`pan`: [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
`bacon`: [(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0)]
Output: *either 0 or an error*.

### Test Case 3:

*What happens when `bacon` crosses itself?*

`pan`: [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
`bacon`:[(0,0),(1,1),(0,1),(1,0)]
Output: *just error here. Any way you feel like. If you manage to report an http 418 error, you get bonus points, redeemable for nothing.*

### Test Case 4:

*What happens if the bacon doesn't exactly overlap the pan?*

`pan`: [(0,0),(0,3),(5,3),(3,0)]
`bacon`: [(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0)]
Output: 2

Comment: This looks like a tough question, but I like it. 1.) Are the coordinates integers or can they be floats? 2.) Is the shape guaranteed to be convex and contain more than two coordinates? 3.) Because this is a code golf challenge, it's unlikely anyone will go for the second output, so you should probably stick with just one of the two output methods. 4.) Example inputs and outputs would be great.

Comment: Having arbitrary polygons make this tough, even just to figure out if one shape fits inside another. I think you'll do well to have extensive test cases that probe at the possibilities and defy heuristics.

Comment: I've added quite a few test cases using minimal `pan`s and `bacon`. @xnor, what do you mean by 'defy heuristics'?

Comment: @JakobLovern Like, for example, making it so that code that just outputs the ratio of the areas doesn't happen to pass all test cases. Other examples could be making sure the code allows bacon to be rotated by non-multiples of 90 degrees, doesn't just try to do some greedy fill from one corner, considers reflecting the bacon, etc. The idea is that someone whose code meets all the tail cases should be reasonably certain it meets the problem conditions.

Comment: @JakobLovern My experience has been that writing the code to do the task has been very helpful to think of edge cases and to generate test cases. You can then post it as (ungolfed) reference code, which is often appreciated by solvers.

Answer (score 1):

## Moore-Penrose inverse

In linear algebra the pseudo-inverse of a matrix is a generalization of the inverse of a matrix which doesn't necessarily exist. One definition of a pseudo-inverse is called the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) which shall be denoted by **A**⁺ in the following. Further let **A**ᵀ denote the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of the matrix **A**.

### Definition

The Moore-Penrose inverse of the matrix **A** is defined for all matrices  **A** in a way such that it satisfies the following four properties:

- **AA⁺A** = **A**
- **A⁺AA⁺** = **A⁺**
- (**AA⁺**)ᵀ = **AA⁺**
- (**A⁺A**)ᵀ = **A⁺A**

### Task

Your task in this challenge is, given a matrix real **A** (non-zero and non-empty) to compute its pseudo-inverse as defined above.

- You're allowed to receive input as a single list, array, list of lists etc.
- The input is a single non-zero, non-empty matrix with real entries
- The input matrix is **not** necessarily square
- Your program/function either returns the pseudo-inverse or prints it to *STDOUT*
- You don't need to handle floating point inaccuracies
- The behavior on invalid input (eg. `[]`) is left undefined

### Examples

Here are some possible examples (note the different (in)accuracies):

```
[4] -> [0.25]
[1 1; 1 0] -> [0 1; 1 -1]
[12 4 9; -9 1 3; -6 6 15] -> [0.0467129 -0.0342457 -0.0217785; 0.0115298 0.0022497 0.0160292; 0.0251844 0.0076240 0.0404324]
[0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0; 2 0 0] -> [0 0 0 0.5; 1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0]
[1 1 2 3] -> [0.0667; 0.0667; 0.1333; 0.2]
[0; 0; 1] -> [0 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0; 2 0 0 0 0] -> [0.2 0.4; 0 0; 0 0; 0 0; 0 0]
```

#### Sandbox

- Should I ban built-ins (looking at Octave/Matlab, Mathematica etc.)?
- Is the part with floating-point inaccuracies formal/objective enough?
- Are more examples needed?

**Tags**: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

Comment: Having no challenge for computing a SVD, maybe I should reduce this to only computing the SVD of a matrix since that would be the heart of this challenge anyway. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

## Different tasks, same characters, [level 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/106125/31516)

In this challenge, you need to solve 3 different tasks using the same set of characters. You can rearrange the characters, but you can't add or remove characters.

The winner will be the submission that solves all tasks using the smallest number of characters. All tasks must be solved in the same language.

Note that it's the smallest number of characters, not the smallest number of unique characters.

**Twist: If one or more characters can be removed from a script without breaking it, then your submission is disqualified.** This means that comments are out of the picture, as well as long variable names to get the character counts to match up.

You do not have to *prove* that it's impossible to remove characters and still have a functioning script, but you should try to make it impossible. If nobody bothers to look at it, then your submission is valid. If nobody sees a way to remove one or more characters, then your submission is valid. If however, someone looks at your post and sees something that can be removed without breaking it, then your submission is invalid.

---

**Tasks:**

I'll create 3 tasks that are fairly simple typical code-golf tasks.

---

So, what do you think about the idea?

Comment: I don't think the twist is going to be easily enforceable.  For any program longer than a dozen bytes the computation time on checking that it fits this requirement becomes immense.

Comment: I think I'll let the burden of disproof (is that a thing?) lie with the viewers. Those posting answers will do their best to make it impossible to remove fluff without breaking it. If someone finds a way to do it, then the submission is invalid. If every character is there for a reason (it has a function) then it should be fairly hard to find something that can be removed that OP wouldn't already know of (for instance reversing something twice). It's not CNR, but if people find ways to golf an answer without breaking it, then it's invalid.

Comment: If nobody bothers to look at it, then your submission is valid. If nobody sees a way to remove one or more characters, then your submission is valid. If however, someone looks at your post and sees something that can be removed without breaking it, then you submission is invalid.

Comment: I think that would be generally effective; in practical languages with longer code, fluff is easier to spot in the syntax, and in recreational golfing languages the shorter code will be easier to manually check.

Comment: So if there exists a subsequence of the original program that also do the task the original program does (not necessarily equivalent), and there is someone point it out, the submission is invalid?

Comment: Do the removed characters need to be contiguous?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork no. It's to avoid stuff like unnecessary long variable names etc. And then you'd need to remove character multiple places...

Comment: Cool! I've had an idea like this, but using different languages to solve the same task (with the exact same twist)

Comment: @Sanchises you may go ahead and post it if you'd like! Either this version or a polyglot version. :) Interested?

Comment: Oh you may have this one. I'm still stuck on thinking of *one* task....

Comment: You have a very nice track record when it comes to challenges, so I'd like to see it :)

Answer (score 1):

## Squaring the circle

### Background

This is a generalization of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/another-loop-of-integers-with-consecutive-terms-adding-to-a-square) on puzzling.SE. Essentially, it asks you to generate a circular array of integers such that any two adjacent integers add to a perfect square, and that the integers are a permutation of those from 1 to 50. The original question gave you a part of the array, and asked you to solve it. I wish to generalize this problem.

### Problem Description

Given an integer `n`, generate a circular array of numbers from 1 to `n` such that any two adjacent integers sum to a perfect square, without repeats of any number.

### Input

Input is limited to positive integers greater than or equal to two.

### Output

If there is no possible array (as can be manually proven to be the case for `n=4`), then your function should gracefully handle the error and exit.

Otherwise, it should output a representation of that array for that `n` as a string of delimited integers, such that, if the string were concatenated into a long integer, it would be the minimum possible string.
To illustrate:

```
1 2 3 
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Of these six representations, only `1 2 3` is in minimal form.

You may delimit your string in any consistent, parsable way you choose.

### Example I/O

For `n<32`, there are no valid arrays (And I can prove it, if necessary.) The smallest `n` with a valid array is `n=32`, and it is structured:

```
=>01 08 28 21 04 32 17 19
15                       30
10                       06
26                       03
23                       13
02                       12
14                       24
22                       25
27                       11
  09 16 20 29 07 18 31 05
```

The output to `n=32`, would therefore be `1 8 28 21 4 32 17 19 30 6 3 13 12 24 25 11 5 31 18 7 29 20 16 9 27 22 14 2 23 26 10 15`

### Example code

Because code is clearer than words, here's a (purposefully) very naive and inefficient  routine for this in Python (2.7):

```
import math, itertools
def main(n):
  def test_if_a_given_list_is_a_ring(input_list):
    is_a_square = lambda value: math.sqrt(value).is_integer()
    output_flag = True
    for index in range(len(input_list)):
      if is_a_square(input_list[index]+input_list[index-1]):
        continue
      else:
        output_flag = False
      #end if
    #end for
    return output_flag
  #end test_if_a_given_list_is_correct
  def turn_it_into_a_string(input_list):
    temp_list = []
    for i in input_list:
      temp_list.append(str(i))
    #end for
    output_string = ''
    for i in temp_list:
      output_list += ' '+ i
    #end for
    return output_list[1:]
  #end turn_it_into_a_string  
 lowest = string(n)*n

 for perm in itertools.permutations(range(n,0,-1)):
    if test_if_a_given_list_is_correct(perm):
      flag = True
      for perm_character,lowest_character in zip(turn_it_into_a_string(perm),lowest):
        if int(lowest_character) < int(perm_character):
          flag = False
          break
        #end if
      #end for
      if flag:
        lowest = turn_it_into_a_string(perm)
      #end if
    #end if
  #end for
  return lowest
#end main
```

If you're gonna golf this code... I'd *highly* recommend optimizing it first.

### Scoring

Programs will be scored based on:
1. Asymptotic complexity
2. Average runtime
3. Byte count
4. Runtime when the byte count is fed into the program as input

(I can't decide which of these scoring systems to use. Note that I've manually worked out that when n<=31, there are no arrays. At n=31, there is a valid double loop system, but no valid single loops.)

Comment: your example is not a valid ring, is it? I only see two perfect squares, `11+5=16` and `1+8=9`

Comment: No, it isn't. As of ten minutes ago, I constructed (By hand) the ring for n=32, so I'll post that.

Comment: (1) "*ring*" has a specific meaning (an algebraic structure with multiplication and addition subject to certain rules), which is distracting. How about changing it to *circular array*? (2) In my opinion, "*generate a [circular array] of numbers from 1 to n*" does not impose a restriction on the length of the array or on the impossibility of repeats. For me the clearest way to add the restrictions which I infer from the linked question would be to say that it's a *permutation* of the numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: (3) "*This is a two part question*": I only see one part. If you intend a follow-up, maybe worth including it so that you can get opinions on whether it would be closed as a dupe of the first part.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was originally intending to ask the question twice, but score using different conditions. I expect that code which would minimize asymptotic complexity wouldn't look at all similar to code which minimizes size. I wanted to see the difference. You made a good point on the dupe problem, though, as the two questions are _essentially_ similar to each other.

Comment: So what's the scoring? If byte-count gets fed to the program no solutions that are < 31 bytes & if it's gonna be an average runtime based scoring you should choose large enough values such that it becomes about complexity and include how you measure.

Comment: That's exactly why I was asking for input on my various ideas for scoring. I don't expect that there's going to be any programs _that_ small that can successfully answer the question, but it could happen. I'm leaning towards asymptotic complexity or byte count.

Answer (score 1):

### Advancing k-combinations

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

[k-combinations for a set of size n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) represent in what different ways one can pick `k` elements out of a set of `n` elements. There is a natural representation of such a pick as an integer with `n` bits, of which exactly `k` are set.

Define `next[n, k] :: Pick(n, k) -> Pick(n, k)` to be the group action that takes each pick to the next one, wrapping around. More formally: Let `r` be an `n`-bit integer with `k` bits set. Then `next[n, k](r)` will return the smallest integer `> r` that also has `k` bits set. If there exists no such integer, the smallest integer with `k` bits is returned. Example: `next[4, 2](0b0011) = 0b0101`, `next[4, 2](0b1100) = 0b0011`.

[- Annotation: if `k = 0`, then there is only one unique integer with zero bits set. `next[n, 0](r) = 0`. -]

You will be given a pick `r` and a positive integer `step`. Output `(next[n, k]^step)(r)`, that is, apply `next[n, k]` `step` times to `r`.

#### Rules

- You will be given 4 integers `n k r step`. Output `(next[n, k]^step)(r)`
- `1 <= n` can be assumed to be small enough to represent picks as integers naturally in your language
- `0 <= k <= n`
- `r` will always be a valid pick of `k` out of `n`.
- `0 <= step <= C(n, k)` can be relatively large. As an example, `C(32, 12) = 225,792,840`

#### Criteria

Return the correct output for all valid inputs.

This is code-golf, shortest code wins.

#### Examples

```
4   2 0b1001 2  => 0b1100
16 10 0xF11F 10 => 0bF15E
4   2 0b1100 2  => 0b0101
```

Comment: Nice challenge! But what if `k = n = 0`? And maybe specify formally how `next` works.

Answer (score 1):

## Simultaneous Selection

In the game [Risk of Rain](https://riskofraingame.com/) there is a game mode where you can select which items you want out of dropped boxes.  The only problem is that when you open two boxes at the same time your movements in one box effect your movements in another.  Now this can be a problem since you may want to retrieve a particular item from one of the boxes.  However there is a solution.

Since the boxes have different shapes and you are not permitted to move your cursor outside of the box you can desynchronize the two cursors.

For example if we have the two boxes

```
S.F...    S.....
......    ...F..
....      .....
```

Where `F` is the goal and `S` is the starting location, we can get the cursor to the goal by moving the cursor

```
Right 4 times
Down 3 times 
Up 1 time
Left 1 time
```

**Still working on it ...**

---

### Input

As input you will receive two 2 dimensional boolean containers, representing the shapes of the boxes. In these boolean arrays `true` means that square exists in the box `false` means square does not exist.  You may assume that your input will be padded with false values such that no true values touches the edge of the array.

You will also receive two coordinate pairs representing the start and end locations.

### Output

You should output a ordered container of "moves" such that when performed on both boxes the cursor will arrive at the end point.  A "move" may be one of 4 chosen values each representing one of the 4 cardinal directions. For example you might choose: `[N,S,E,W]`, `[1,2,3,4]` or `[(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)]`.  Your program must be self consistent in these values across multiple sessions.

If no solution is possible for the given boxes you must output a value that is distinct from any possible sequence of moves, for example a list containing a 5th value that cannot represent a move, or a non list item.

**Still working on it ...**

Comment: How do we take input? As two separate strings or can it be arrays, etc...

Comment: @Neil Its going to be boolean arrays, `true` means square exists `false` means square does not exist, and coordinates for start and end locations.  I've been a little lazy in finishing this question.

Answer (score 1):

## Best Yahtzee score

Yahtzee is a game played with five six-sided dice and a score sheet with thirteen different boxes to fill a score in. Each box has its own scoring rules:

- 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, 6s all score points equal to the sum of the respective dice (that is, a roll of [3, 2, 3, 1, 5] scored as 3s would be awarded 6 points - 3 for each 3).
- 3-of-a-kind and 4-of-a-kind (as they sound, three or four dice rolled the same) score points equal to the sum of all five dice.
- Full house (two dice show one value, the other three show another) scores 25 points
- Small straight (four consecutive values) scores 30 points
- Large straight (all consecutive values) scores 40 points
- Yahtzee (all dice show the same value) scores 50 points

The thirteenth (chance) makes sense in-game, but not so much for this challenge; additionally the game has bonuses for extra Yahtzees which make no sense here. Because the challenge is...

Given five dice as input (five integers 1-6, input however is convenient), output the highest score that roll can score <s>as well as what box it's being score under</s>. The score should be output as its decimal numeric value, whether that's an integer or a string representation thereof, whatever. It should be immediately recognizable as a number. <s>How you identify boxes is up to you so long as they are all unique and any given roll that will be scored in a given box always returns the same value. Please specify in your answer how boxes are identified. Order ([score, box] or [box, score]) does not matter. If you're outputting to STDOUT or otherwise not returning two values from a function, please separate score and box with at least one non-alphanumeric character of your choosing.</s>

Code golf, so shortest answer in a given language wins. Standard loopholes apply.

Test cases<s>, using `,` as separator, and `123456kKfsly` for the box names (respective of their order above)</s>:

```
in: 1 5 4 3 2
out: 40
in: 1 1 4 3 1
out: 10
in: 1 1 6 5 3
out: 6
```

---

### Sandbox/meta

- I saw one existing Yahtzee challenge, but IIRC it boiled down to scoring a whole game. I did the 'given five dice, what is the best score' exercise once and felt like there were some interesting challenges to be found in optimizing it.
- Better ways to express I/O? I want it to be flexible but relatively readable...
- My first potential submission, I'm sure I'm forgetting something...

Comment: IMO, multi parts output is pretty much a party killer. In that specific question, I think **the score itself** is enough to constitute a nice challenge. The box value is drived by conditional programming, which (of the challenge goes well) might not be present in some answers.

Comment: Anyway, for that wide range of possibilities, you should add at least one test case to cover collisions, multiple scorings and at least one of each box type (again, as I see challenges here)

Comment: @Uriel Thanks for the input — I planned to fill in more test cases, I guess I could've mentioned that in the meta section. I'm not trying to be difficult, but I'm curious if you could expand on your other point w/ the score itself being enough. The score is (I believe?) entirely dependent on the box being determined, and spitting _something_ box-related out seems programmatically like a small challenge vs. the 'reward' of the output. This was why I wanted that output to be very flexible. Part of me thinks you're right, part of me thinks I'm right… so if you have more to say, please do…

Comment: my point is, in order to get the right score the user necessarily went through the right box (and not even print it, but also did a somewhat-more-complex calculation with it) - so it's kinda like letting them output twice.

Comment: @Uriel Makes sense, and I was leaning that way the more I thought about it last night. Cutting it also eliminates the need to address collisions. I think it's out... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Google Doodle Kids Coding-style simulator

One input is a list of commands. There are three action commands and a loop construct. There is some flexibility as to the command format:

- As a string or equivalent: The loop construct should use a pair of matching brackets. The direction commands should be `<` and `>` or `L` and `R` (either case). The motion command should be `^` or `F`.
- As a list of characters: The loop construct should be a sublist. The other commands should be individual characters in the list, specified as above.
- As a list of integers: The direction commands should be `-1` and `1` while the motion command should be `0`.

The other input is the starting position. This consists of an two-dimensional array in any suitable format (including a newline-separated string). Background values should be represented using `0` or spaces. Carrots should be represented using `-1`, `^` or `V` (either case). The starting square should be represented using `1`, `@`, or `R` (either case).

Optionally, the starting direction can be an input (one of `<>V^` or an angle in degrees or turns), or it can be hard-coded (please specify the default starting direction in this case).

Command rules:

- Loops always execute four times
- The direction commands rotate the rabbit in place
- The motion command moves the rabbit one square in the current direction

The rabbit wins if it eats all of the carrots.

The rabbit dies if:

- It runs out of commands
- It walks out of bounds
- It walks onto the background

The starting square and carrot squares are all safe.

Your output should be a consistent truthy value if the rabbit wins, and a consistent falsy value if it dies. This can also be achieved by exception or error exit.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14318/47066)

Comment: What's the background?

Comment: 1) exception exit is already a standard way to output a falsey value, and 2) in the actual Google doodle you don't lose if you try to walk off the edge of the map, it just does nothing.

Comment: @StephenLeppik It's not meant to exactly simulate the Doodle.

Comment: By "background" I means as in "It walks onto the background".

Comment: @user202729 The background is any square whose value is 0 or space depending on your input format.

Comment: Ready to post to main?

Comment: Don't abandon this... :(

Answer (score 1):

## Coin Game: Shoot It Out!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

---

In Shoot It Out, we will play with coins on a table.

## Basic Idea

Shoot It Out is a 6-player game. The players will be split into two teams of 3 players, one offensive, and one defensive.

Initially, every player has a coin on the table. Additionally, there is a target coin. Players take turns to shoot their coin. However, the shots will not be very accurate.

The offensive team will try to shoot the target coin out of the table, while the defensive team tries to prevent the target coin from being shot out. You should make a bot that can play as both offensive and defensive team, and try to maximize the winning rate.

## Rules

#### Playing Order

- Every player has its player ID. ID 1, 3, 5 are on the offensive team; ID 0, 2, 4 are on the defensive team.
- Playing order is the same as ID. After the turn of ID 5 is ID 0's turn. If a player is removed, simply go to the next player.
- When it is a player's turn, they will shoot their coin once. After every coin stopped moving, the turn ends.

#### Elimination in a Game

- If a player shoots their own coin out of the table, the player is removed from the game. If the target coin moves out of the table in the same turn, it will be placed back to the previous position.
- If a player shoots another player's coin out of the table, both players are removed from the game.

(Note that these two can occur in the same turn.)

#### Winning Conditions

- Defensive team wins when **both** conditions below are satisfied:

  - The target coin is in the table area.
  - All players on the offensive team are removed, or 18 turns have been played (skipped turn is not counted).
- Offensive team wins when one of the conditions below are satisfied:

  - The target coin is out of the table area.
  - All players on the defensive team are removed.
- There is one exception: if all players are removed at the end of a turn, the defensive team wins.

#### Table Settings / Parameters

- The table is a circular area of radius 100 cm. The radius of every coin is 1 cm. A coin is out of table iff its center is out of the circular area.
- For convenience, we set the coordinate of the center of the table to (0, 0), and denote the position of a coin by the coordinate of its center.
- The coefficient of restitution between coins is 0.9.
- The maximum intended speed of a shot is 240 cm/s.
- When a coin is moving, it will have an acceleration of -240 cm/s^2 (due to friction).
- When the game starts, the target coin is located at (0, 0), while the coin of ID `x` is located at `(2.5 cos(f(x)*pi/3), 2.5 sin(f(x)*pi/3))`. The values of f(x) are:

```
x f(x)
0 0
1 3
2 1
3 4
4 5
5 2
```

Here is a picture of initial positions.

[image]

## Errors

Each player's shot has two parameters: angle and initial speed. Programs will output the two parameters representing its intended shot. However, the actual shot won't be the same of what is intended: errors will be added into parameters.

Specifically, if the angle (in radians) and initial speed (in cm/s) of the intended shot are `θ, v`, then:

- The actual angle will be `θ+R(pi/70)`.
- The actual initial speed will be `v*exp(R(1/12))`. (Note that it may exceed the maximum speed.)

Where `R(x)` is a random variable with Gaussian distribution of standard deviation `x` and average 0.

## Scoring

Since only 6 players can play in one game, the controller will randomly assign players to a game.

Lots of games will be held until each player has played both defensive and offensive team in more than 10000 games.

The final score of your program will be `y/x+z/(1-x)`, where:

- `x` is the average winning rate of offensive team in all games.
- `y` is the winning rate of your program when on the offensive team.
- `z` is the winning rate of your program when on the defensive team.

## Input / Output

Your program will be run once per game. It should receive inputs from stdin and output to stdout.

At the beginning of a game, it will receive a line of input `a`, where `a` is the player ID (thus indicating which team you should play in).

When a turn starts, you will receive input like this:

```
3
0 3.798 3.332
1 12.656 3.666
3 18.652 7.913
4 8.004 7.132
6 -3.187 -9.553
```

The first line indicates the player of this turn. Each remaining line contains information of a coin: The first number is the player ID of the coin's owner (or 6 if it is the target coin). The remaining two numbers are x and y coordinates of the center of the coin.

If it is your turn, you should output two numbers, separated by a newline or space, representing the intended angle (in radians, 0 is +x, pi/2 is +y) and initial speed (in cm/s). You should flush stdout after output. (If it is not your turn, you should not output anything.)

You needn't to handle the termination of your program. When the game ends (or you are removed), the controller will send SIGKILL to your program to terminate it.

## Specifications

- Your program should be able to be compiled into an executable, or be executed like an executable (for example, add shebang if you use interpreted languages). If your program need to be compiled to run, you should also specify how to compile your program.
- Your program should not access files, or anything that stores information between games.
- Your program should be deterministic. You can use random number generators, but you should make sure that the generator you use is based on a fixed seed, and will not use random devices (such as RDRAND or /dev/random), system time, etc.
- All "random" numbers (while generating errors and assigning players) used by the controller are generated in a deterministic way. However, your program should not take any advantage of it.
- The total response time of your program in a game should not exceed 0.1 second.
- You can submit multiple programs, but they should not team up against the others.

## Controller & Sample Bots

(Still working on them...)

Answer (score 1):

## Tell my browser

## Background

Many people visit webpages, which require special browsers because of lack of compatibility. So you have to write a script (client sided or server sided), which just prints the name of the browser. Because not everyone has fast internet, the script has to be as short as possible.

## Rules

1. You have to print the name of the browser loading the page without any version number etc. to STDOUT or equivalent. Leading or trailing spaces are allowed.
2. You can assume the browser is Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari or Opera, so only those browsers will be tested. Don't print "Chromium", this does NOT count.
3. The script may be server sided with CGI (in any language), ruby on rails, jsp and similar. Client sided scripts may be written in JavaScript, TypeScript, and any other versions of ECMAScript, it just has to run in all five browsers.
4. If your language has no offline interpreter for CGI, assume it's saved in /usr/bin/i, the shebang at the beginning does not add bytes to the count.
5. this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

## Meta

- Does this question have important loopholes?
- Is there any language which cannot be programmed in? (CGI should work always, even Java or bf could be done with a shebang, lol)

Comment: About the "Is there any language which cannot be programmed in?" --- that's actually a very good question. Let me try.

Comment: About the background... "fast internet" doesn't matter if the script is server-side.

Comment: @user202729  This is a joke, lol, just like those other joke reasons the program has to be short. Is it a good question though?

Comment: Probably. But the fact is, not everyone is familiar with writing a server, so you may not get a lot of answers.

Answer (score 1):

## The 64 | 64 Color Selector

All colour selector tools suck. Let us make another one that sucks also, but in a different way.

Your interface will have:

- two squares, of 64x64 "pixels" each one. Pixels do **not** need to be strictly pixels, but anything where the user can have 64 possible selections in each direction, vertical or horizontal, representing all the possible different RGB colors.
- a third element of the interface that will represent the color selected with user has selected based picked on squares.
- a fourth element which represents the 6 digit hexadecimal RGB hex-code (example: #FFBF32). You can divide it in three elements, but you have to make clear which component is what from RGB.
- a fifth element which represent the decimal RGB code (example RGB(127,33,43)). You can also divide it in three elements, but you have to make clear which component is what from RGB.

When the two squares are at the top left corner, selected color must be RGB(0,0,0); and when the two squares at the bottom right corner must be RGB(255,255,255).

You must have the the pixels in the square sorted by increasing order; I don't care what direction, vertical or horizontal, you choose for increasing one-by-one, but the two squares must have the same pattern.

When the user picks a "pixel" in the first square, the colours of the second must be updated and reflect all possible values under the second pixel.

When the user picks a "pixel" in the second square, 3rd, 4th and 5th elements must be updated to reflect new color selection.

Code-golf, but there will be no accepted answer, as it discourages people from adding new answers when they see already posted very short answers.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)

Comment: Your specifications seem a bit too loosely-defined to me, though unfortunately I don't have any suggestions for improvement at the current moment

Comment: I assume that your first requirement should state 'Pixels do **not** need to be strictly pixels...'

Comment: @brhfl Yes. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Is there any requirement on the ordering of selections in the first two elements, or is it fine as long as every RGB color could be expressed as a coordinate pair on the first element plus a coordinate pair on the second element?

Comment: @KamilDrakari: Yes. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: better now?

Comment: It looks good, you may want to point out that you want a 1:1 color conversion.  I was looking at it and I think that's what you want since 64^4 = 256^3.

Comment: "*You must have the the pixels in the square sorted by increasing order*" is nonsense unless you address the issue that HyperNeutrino raised about the specifications not truly being specifications.

Answer (score 1):

## Destroy the Computers with Magnets!

The robot apocalypse has finally arrived. But as we all know, robots are controlled by computers. And magnets are a convenient way of disabling computers.

**Your task:** place the magnet close enough to the computer so that it disables the computer.

A computer looks like this (always the exact same size):

```
 ____
|    |
|    |
|____|
```

The magnet looks like this:

```
o
```

The magnet needs to be touching the computer to do its work:

```
 o____o
o|    |o
o|    |o
o|____|o
 oooooo
```

Note the lack of placements on the top; that is intentional. People use the computer on that side, and would easily see the magnet and remove it.

So if you are given a picture of some computers:

```
       ____
      |    |
 ____ |    |
|    ||____|
|    |      ____
|____|     |    |
           |    |
           |____|
```

You should place 1 magnet for computer next to the computers:

```
       ____
      |    |
 ____ |    |
|    ||____|
|    |  o   ____
|____|     |    |
 o        o|    |
           |____|
```

Magnets may touch computers, but there must be 1 touching magnet per computer.

Due to the apocalypse, resources are scarce, so your program to place magnets must be as short as possible.

**Test cases:**

```
Input
~~~~~
Example outputs (not only possible outputs)
=====
       ____
      |    |
 ____ |    |
|    ||____|
|    |      ____
|____|     |    |
           |    |
           |____|
~~~~~
       ____
      |    |
 ____ |    |
|    ||____|
|    |  o   ____
|____|     |    |
 o        o|    |
           |____|

        ____
       |    |
  ____ |    |o
 |    ||____|
 |    |     o____
o|____|     |    |
            |    |
            |____|
=====
More soon....
```

Comment: Is it permissible for a "component" to be adjacent to multiple voting machines? For example, with two voting boxes 1 space apart, would placing two components in that column be valid?

Comment: @KamilDrakari That is allowed, I will edit.

Comment: Would [these](https://pastebin.com/raw/AipBvUzZ) be valid outputs? Also is the voting machine always the same size?

Comment: @BruceForte Those are all valid outputs except for number 4: there must be at least 1 physical component per voting machine (as it says in the challenge.) Voting machines are all the same size. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

## Demolish a string! v2

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A modified version of [Demolish a String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/145217/60043); since the original question involved randomness, the challenge was too complex and there were not many answers. This challenge removes the criterion and allows flexibility by the answerer, which should invite responses in languages without randomness built-ins.

## Challenge

Given a string input, output the demolished version of it.

## The Process

```
P
r      Pr       r
o       o       o
g       g       g
r       r       r      rogr         r
a  ->   a  ->   a  ->     a  ->     a  ->           ->           ->           ->           ->  
m       m       m         m         m
m       m       m         m         m         mmar         m
i       i       i         i         i         i            i           mi           m
n       n       n         n        gn        gn           gn           gn           gni         mgni
g       g      Pg        Pg      roPg      roPg         roPgmar      roPgmar      roPgmar      roPgmar
```

Place the string vertically. Repeat the following steps until they are impossible:

1. Take any column of characters that can be demolished (explained below)
2. Select some integer between `1` and `(height of the column of characters) - 1` and some direction (left or right).
3. Rotate that number of characters in that direction (only if those spaces are unoccupied; if not, go back to step 3).
4. Let those characters fall due to gravity.

At the end, the output should be a string whose heights of consecutive columns differ by at most one.

**Note: the choice of integers and the direction is up to the answerer**

If there are space characters in the input, demolish those first, all at once.

```
C
o

d      
e  ->     oC  ->         ->  ...
       de         
G        G          G
o        o          o
l        l          l
f        f        defoC
```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Trailing and leading newlines are allowed.
- Your program may either print or return a string/equivalent.
- Please explain the demolition algorithm (`# of characters` and `direction`) in your answer.

### Some test cases to try

```
A
Programming
Code Golf
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submissions with the smallest byte counts in their languages win!

Answer (score 1):

## What is the simplest reversible circuit that computes conjugacy of transpositions?

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math),[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations),[logic-gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates)

## Motivation

Reversible computation refers to computation in which little or no information is deleted. Reversible computation a major component of quantum computation, and reversible computation is potentially many times more energy efficient than conventional computation. I want to know how easy it is to compute the conjugacy of transpositions reversibly?

## Challenge

Let `T5` be the set of all transpositions on the set `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Let `*` be the [conjugacy operation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Conjugation.html) on `T5` defined by `x * y=xyx^(-1)` (here concatenation denotes the [group operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group)). In other words, the underlying set of `T5` consists of all 10 pairs `(a,b)` of distinct numbers from `{1,2,3,4,5}` and where we declare `(a,b)=(b,a)`. The operation `*` is the unique operation on the underlying set that satisfies

- `(a,b) * (c,d)=(c,d)`,
- `(a,b) * (b,c)=(a,c)`,
- `(a,b) * (a,b)=(a,b)`

whenever `a,b,c,d` are distinct.

What is the simplest `n` bit input reversible circuit `C` along with an injective function `R:T5->{0,1}^n` such that `C(R(x),R(y))=(R(x),R(x*y))` for all `x,y` in `T5`?

The gate cost of a reversible circuit shall be the sum of the costs of every individual logic gate in the reversible circuit.

Here is the price chart per logic gate (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) for a description of the logic gates) along with a description of the reversible gates.

Each SWAP gate `(x,y)->(y,x)` will have a cost of `0`.

Each [NOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate)) `x-> NOT x` shall have a cost of `1`.

Each [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) `(x,y)->(x,x XOR y)` shall have a cost of `2`.

Each [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate) `(x,y,z)->(x,(NOT x AND y) OR (x AND z),(x AND y) OR (NOT x AND z))` shall have a cost of `4` (the Fredkin gate can also be described as the reversible logic gate where `(0,x,y)->(0,x,y)` and `(1,x,y)->(1,y,x)`).

Each [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) `(x,y,z)->(x,y,(x AND y) XOR z)` shall have a cost of `5`.

No other gates are allowed.

Observe that each reversible gate has the same number of inputs as it has outputs (this feature is required for all reversible gates).

The complexity of your circuit will be the product of the gate cost or your circuit with the number `n` which you choose. The goal of this challenge will be to minimize this measure of complexity.

## Format

Complexity: This is your final score. The complexity is the product of the number `n` with your total gate cost.

Space: State the number `n` of bits that your circuit `C` acts on.

Total gate cost: State the sum of the costs of each of the individual gates in your circuit `C`.

NOT gate count: State the number of NOT gates.

CNOT gate count: State the number of CNOT gates.

Toffoli gate count: How many Toffoli gates are there?

Fredkin gate count: How many Fredkin gates are there?

Legend: Give a description of the function `R`. For example, you may write

`(1,2)->0000,(1,3)->0001,(1,4)->0010,(1,5)->0011,(2,3)->0100,
(2,4)->0101,(2,5)->0110,(3,4)->0111,(3,5)->1000,(4,5)->1001`.

Gate list: Here list the gates in the circuit `C` from first to last. Each gate shall be written in the form [Gate type abbreviation,lines where the gates come from]. For this problem, we shall start with the 0th bit. The following list specifies the abbreviations for the type of gates.

`T`-Toffoli gate
`S`-Swap gate
`C`-CNOT gate
`F`-Fredkin gate
`N`-Not gate.

For example, `[T,1,5,3]` would denote a Toffoli gate acting on the 1st bit, the 5th bit, and the 3rd bit. For example, `[T,2,4,6]` produces the transformation `01101010->01101000` and `[C,2,1]` produces `011->001,010->010` and `[N,3]` produces `0101->0100`. For example, one could write
`[S,7,3],[N,2],[T,1,2,3],[F,1,2,5],[C,7,5]`
for the gate list.

The gates act on the bit string from left to right. For example, the gate list `[C,0,1],[C,1,0]` will produce the transformation `01->11`.

## Sample answer

Complexity: `80`

Space: `5`

Total gate cost: `16`

NOT gate count: `3`

CNOT gate count: `2`

Toffoli gate count: `1`

Fredkin gate count: `1`

Legend: `(1,2)->00001,(1,3)->00011,(1,4)->00101,(1,5)->00110,(2,3)->01000,(2,4)->01011,(2,5)->01100,(3,4)->01110,(3,5)->10001,(4,5)->10011`

Gate list: `[N,1],[N,0],[N,4],[S,1,2],[S,2,3],[C,0,1],[C,2,3],[T,3,2,1],[F,4,3,2,1]`

## Sandbox

Comment: It would be helpful to define conjugacy, transposition and the group operation. If the challenge is to write a program that does these things then you should specify that along with desired input/output format and winning criterium (e.g. shortest code, fastest code, custom scoring, etc.)

Comment: is `x^(-1)` the inverse of `x` on the group?

Comment: Yes. x^(-1) denotes the inverse of x in the group. For transpositions x, we have x^(-1)=x.

Comment: It would be helpful if you format the code properly.

Comment: "*The operation * is the unique operation on the underlying set that satisfies (a,b) * (c,d)=(c,d),(a,b) * (b,c)=(a,c),(a,b) * (a,b) whenever a,b,c,d are distinct.*" I find that list hard to read with the whitespace as is, but is it incomplete? I think it's missing `= (a,b)` at the end. For readability, I suggest either using code markup separately for each identity or putting them in an unordered list.

Comment: I think the `C` on the right hand side of the condition is wrong.

Comment: After reading this a few more times, I find that I'm uncertain as to what branching is allowed. Can I use the same value as input to more than one gate, or is a line "used up" when it goes into a gate? Also, are constant 0 and 1 available, or do they have to be included as extra bits in the output of R?

Comment: Sorry for being away for a while. I am going to get back to editing this proposed challenge so that it will be up and ready as soon as possible.

Comment: @PeterTaylor. Reversible circuits do not have any branching. Every reversible gate has the same number of input bits as it has output bits. I will clarify this in the post.

Answer (score 1):

## Squeeze Out a Square Quine

...the bigger the better.

#### Task

Write a full program that is a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/61405) (a piece of
code that outputs itself without reading its source code). To make things more difficult, your code (and obviously
the output) has to be in a form of a square, meaning that your code must consist of `n` lines of length `n` (not
counting the newline to the line length).

#### Scoring

Your answer's score will be `n`, the side length of the square. **The largest square quine wins.** To avoid
answers being padded to create arbitrarily large squares, your code must fail to be a proper quine if any single
non-newline character is replaced by some other character that appears in the code. There must be, at minimum, two different non-newline characters in the code.

---

For example, if your code was...

```
abc
def
ghi
```

...and would output itself, your answer would be valid and its score would be `3`.

A single trailing newline in the output is allowed.

[code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

Comment: Replace single character at one places or multiple characters at multiple places?

Comment: @user202729 I was thinking of single character at one place, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient.

Comment: If it's a quine then surely it should be a trailing newline in the code

Comment: In that case it should be "the source code and the output may differ at the trailing newline". Also, if the restriction is "multiple character at multiple places" then it would be near impossible, because it's likely that there are multiple valid programs for each square size.

Comment: I like the challenge but at a certain size, checking a solution for its validity will be impossible. What if someone posts a solution and failed to notice some weird replacement that would render that submission invalid?

Comment: @BruceForte Yeah, it's pretty problematic a challenge. I'm not sure what to do with it. Perhaps it would work better as [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 1):

> Any comments for improvement would be appreciated.
> Should I choose a harder function? (maybe "Is this binary number prime?")
> Or maybe not harder, but some other decision problem suggestion?

## Majority function, a non-uniform computing challenge

Non-uniform computing is a class of computing where a different procedure can be specified for each input size of a problem.  This allows discussing complexity of languages that are only straight line computations (no looping constructs), yet which are powerful enough to compute any fixed input size function a Turing machine can compute. It also allows taking advantage of algorithms that may work well if only you could tweak a parameter for each size (even if the parameter is difficult to compute) or where there are only a small number of exceptions in each input size (so checking those exceptions then using the algorithm succeeds).

## Goal:

Write a program or function which, given an input length, outputs an If-Then-Else sequence (defined below) which determines if greater than half the inputs are 1 (the majority function).

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). Your score will be:

```
G20 + 4*G5 + 10*G2 + L
```

Where `L` is the size of your submission in bytes, and `G20` is the length of the generated If-Then-Else sequence for size=20 (length being defined as number of If-Then-Else statements).  Similarly `G5` and `G2` are the lengths for the generated programs for size=5 and size=2 respectively. The lowest score wins.

This is in some sense an "inception" code golf. You will be judged on the
length of your program as well as the length of the programs it generates.

To prevent submissions that just loop over all possible ITE sequences till it
finds the smallest one that works, entries need to provide the `G20`, `G5`, `G2` values along with the code submission for it to be a valid entry.
As the number of possible sequences quickly becomes infeasible to search, this should eliminate raw brute forcing.

#### If-Then-Else "programs"

An If-Then-Else (ITE) statement is a logical statement of the form:

```
if A then B else C
```

The logical value of this statement is referred to as the "output", and the values A, B, and C are the "inputs" of the statement. To turn this into a formatted language, a file (or string) describing an ITE program will be a series of lines that contain:

```
<input_term> <space> <input_term> <space> <input_term>
```

Where an input_term is one of:

- `'0'`
- `'1'`
- `'I' <decimal_number>`
- `'Q' <decimal_number>`

The values 0 and 1 are Boolean false and true respectively. The value of I(number) is the value of the input at index 'number';
for example I3 = Input #3 (input numbering starts at zero).
The value of Q(x) is the result of ITE statement number 'x' (again, numbering starts at zero).

The result of an ITE program is the output of its last statement.

#### Example ITE program

Here is a simple interpreter for ITE programs, written in python:
[ite.py](https://pastebin.com/nyziRDpk)

This interpreter has some additional features like comments (start a line with `#`) and custom output names (start line with `<name>:` ) which are useful when playing with some ideas by hand. If you choose to utilize those features in your generated ITE programs, that's fine, although I'm not sure how that would help.  This will be considered the defacto standard for the ITE language for this competition.

Here is an example program: parity4.ite

```
I0 0 1
I1 Q0 I0
Q1 0 1
I2 Q2 Q1
Q3 0 1
I3 Q4 Q3
```

As its name suggests, this is the parity function for input size 4. It returns 1 if the 4 inputs bits have an odd number of 1s, otherwise it returns 0. Here is an example of testing it on some values.

```
$ python ite.py parity4.ite 0110
0
$ python ite.py parity4.ite 0111
1
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, this is a great challenge! I haven't put much thought into it but what's the reason for such a high weight on *G2*? *G2* could become a special case for some clever approaches (just a guess) in which case it would be quite a hefty penalty (or they would have to hardcode its output).

Comment: @BMO I think the required number of statements may scale roughly proportional to the number of inputs. So I was trying to "weight" them evenly. Now that you mention it, G2=1 is possible, so maybe that is not a good one.

Comment: I was hoping to test both a "small" input size (easy to solve by hand), "medium" input size (hopefully possible to at least follow by hand), and "large" input size (probably too big to follow by hand). I guess G2 is too small. Maybe it would be better to just check G20 and G5?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, so it's difficult to say but G2 is not very interesting and it has quite a significant weight. I didn't mean that you should exclude it, but maybe it's a good idea or at least change the weights - maybe using G3 would be an option as well, I think it's a good idea to use small ones that are verifiable by hand. Tbh. finding out a good weighting system is not easy, maybe others with experience could help you out there?

Answer (score 1):

## Square Number Chains

#### Background

Given a positive integer `n >= 25`, it is conjectured that there exists a permutation of the positive integers which are less than or equal to `n` in which every adjacent pair of numbers adds up to a square number. There are also several numbers less than 25 that this is also true for - 15, 16, 17, and 23.

#### The Challenge

Write a program or function which accepts a positive integer, `n`, and returns all positive integers less than or equal to `n`, ordered such that each adjacent pair adds up to a square number. If there are multiple valid orderings, only one needs to be returned, but your program must be deterministic - that is, for a particular input, your answer should return the same output every time.

You can assume that the input will always have at least one solution, so you don't have to deal with inputs 1-14, 18-22, or 24. If you prefer, you can require that input to your submission will always be greater than 24 - if so, please specify in your submission.

Output may be in the form of a list, or written to STDOUT, so long as there is a consistent and identifiable seperator between them - for example, a space, newline, comma, tab, etc are all fine.

You can validate your program's output by using [this TIO link](https://tio.run/##ZZDLbsIwEEX3/oqRVwlMEYbSl8SiYtsd3SEWFjHFUrCD7VSgKN@ejsMjhK5G9sy9Z@4Up7CzZto0vsh1WOykk5ugHMyBI2dMm6IMn87JE/2stAnJMYWtdXAEbaDtJumo1SZ9h3RNar@w@yJXQZHaWxdUlnSOKczJ89jZOWl@VCIQcmV6c0MQZFe4yOdLdSiV2SjQHqp6cwHwEdnsJfU56C3ckVXuFXBjA/A0ZexX5jqjdb5dqVhE6w49/o9@IvQHA/DlnkRdZ6XXtNb9eyjWNKf98lBKFwMncd2oGwxgNEtjmbSZ6Y8mL3GqeljV86pGCuNb6S1Kj4aPMIw@CNe8F2w/LcA17rlKk91GGbte9Ev7cL7mecrbvAzamoeb3ls8XFcbojXNO77iBMUzCoEzpEKPKU7xBcUYxQwFvv0B). It supports input as a string with any consistent separator, and will tell you what criteria (if any) your list is failing on.

#### Inspiration

[The Square-Sum Problem - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY)

#### Test cases

```
Input    Example output
15       9,7,2,14,11,5,4,12,13,3,6,10,15,1,8
23       18,7,9,16,20,5,11,14,2,23,13,12,4,21,15,10,6,19,17,8,1,3,22
```

#### Winning Criteria

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes will be the winner! Good luck and happy golfing!

---

#### TODO

-More test cases

### Feedback requested:

The Python program I've thrown together to provide solution verification is probably a bit shonky, I'm not that strong a Python programmer. If anyone has any comment/criticisms feel free to let me know, or improve it yourself!

As has been pointed out that this challenge is similar to a few others which ask for a Hamiltonian cycle. In my opinion this is suitably different, as this is looking for a Hamiltonian path, and the input is far simpler than the other challenges. What do people think?

Comment: Numberphile's conjecture :P

Comment: What's the winning criterion? Since the conjecture talks about integers `>= 25`, you should add testcases for those and probably restrict input to that range as well.

Comment: @BMO Oops, you're right, I'd forgotten to mention that this is intended to be code golf, good spot. I've mentioned in the 2nd paragraph of The Challenge that you can expect the input to result in at least one solution, does that cover your concern about restricting the input range?

Comment: Dupewatch: this is Hamiltonian path, which is rather similar to Hamiltonian cycle, which has been done at least three times: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11310/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31898/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67611/194

Comment: @Sok: Yeah I read that I just thought that it'll make the challenge more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

## Solve the Square-Sum problem

Based on these (very good) Numberphile videos:

[The Square-Sum problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY) and its [extra footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_ph5djCCnM).

#### The Problem:

Given a list of integer numbers `[1,n]` where `n≥15; n≠18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24`, your task is to arrange those numbers in a way such that the sum of two consecutive numbers is a square number.

Example for `n=15`:

```
Original sequence: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
Square-sum of it: 8 1 15 10 6 3 13 12 4 5 11 14 2 7 9
                   | |  |  | | |  |  | | |  |  | | |
                  3² 4² 5² 4²3²4² 5² 4²3²4² 5² 4²3²4²
```

This problem can be solved by creating a graph of every sum of two numbers in the sequence that result in a square number:

[image: Graph]

From that graph, it's possible to find its [Hamiltonian Path](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html):

[image: Hamiltonian Path]

This path, if existing, is the solution to the square-sum problem.

#### Rules:

---Under Construction---

#### Sandbox:

- Suggestions?
- Dupe?
- Test cases are under construction

Comment: [Sandbox dupe](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14571/59487).

Answer (score 1):

## Word ladder

A [word ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder) is a puzzle where the aim is to create the smallest sequence of steps between two fixed words (a starting word and a target word), where each step changes one letter to produce a new word.  All the intermediate words must be recognised in a dictionary (which will be supplied).

If the target word is longer than the starting word, a step may *add* a letter at any position instead of changing one; if it's shorter than the starting word, a step may *remove* a letter instead of changing one.

Examples:

```
HAND
BAND
BOND
FOND
FOOD
FOOT
```

```
FINGER
FINER
FINE
TINE
TONE
TOE
```

```
EYES
EYED
DYED
DEED
TEED
TEND
TENT
TENTH
TEETH
```

### The challenge

Write a program or function which accepts a dictionary of words and the two fixed words (i.e. a starting word and a target word), and produces an ordered list of intermediate words following the rules above.  You may choose to output the starting word, the target word, both, or neither.

You may use any of the standard methods of input and output, and must not bypass the rules with any of the standard loopholes.

### Scoring

> ***(I need some help with this part).***

The score is the number of dictionary lookups your program makes during a test run (or average of several test runs, if it's not deterministic) on a set of inputs with a simple English dictionary.  ***Q: does this test set need to be prepared and included in the question?***

---

## Sandbox questions

I don't really want to make this a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), as we'll just end up with simple brute-force algorithms; I really want to see creative use of the dictionary, either by pre-processing or perhaps by ordering candidate words.

Is there a way we can define a "dictionary lookup" and somehow separate the word generation/validation from knowledge of the fixed words, without making assumptions that the language has functions or other methods of isolating code?

Can we require the dictionary to be a separate process, and provide a reference implementation?  I don't think we can, without excluding languages without reasonable inter-process communication (I'm thinking of PostScript, possibly JavaScript, and microcomputer BASIC).

Comment: I think this could be a [tag:test-battery] challenge, with both different words and different dictionaries as tests. Different dictionaries are needed to avoid languages searching in a build-in English dictionary and only validating their finds in the provided dict.

Comment: I mentioned English because I would like entries to be able to use heuristics to choose a good way to search first - perhaps simple vowel/consonant rules, perhaps something more sophisticated (digraph tables?).  Promising an arbitrary dictionary would prevent that kind of thinking, especially if there's nothing to say that "XYQQZ" won't be in it.  @Laikoni, could your concern be addressed by a rule to outlaw built-in dictionaries?  ("You must use only the supplied dictionary", for example)

Comment: I see your point and also like the idea to incentive some form of language processing. However banning built-in dictionaries comes with the general problem of banning built-ins, namely what counts as a built-in dictionary. Just from the top of my head, if the scoring is only about look-ups in a provided English dictionary and built-in dicts as well as adding a dict in to your code are a banned, how about assessing built-in texts to sample a rough dictionary? I know that some languages can asses their own documentation from within the language itself.

Comment: Altogether, it might be a good idea to make the score a weighted combination of code length and the number of lookups.

Comment: How would you define "dictionary lookup"? A program may "copy" the dictionary and count that as one dictionary lookup. A check whether a word is in the dictionary? ***///*** Also for the problem of built-in dictionary the solution is really simple: scramble the letters, and use different languages, or just use a random dictionary. For example `bunny` with the scramble `b->x, u->y, n->q, y->z` may well become `xyqqz`, and of course it won't change the challenge. ***///*** What if there is no solution?

Comment: The core question is essentially https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2478/194 so as [tag:code-golf] I would vote to close this as a dupe. But with the current rules (and in particular the requirement to produce the smallest sequence of steps) I'm not sure how viable the proposed scoring system is. Basically answers will have to be equivalent to A* and there aren't that many admissible heuristics. In particular, heuristics for whether something is a word or not would only meet spec if they encode the entire dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Peter and others. I didn't manage to find the code-golf version, so the link is useful.  I obviously need to think a bit further about the rules and scoring (in fact, I posted to Sandbox hoping to garner further ideas).  I'm starting to agree that the dictionary can be abstract if the answer is allowed to generate heuristics from it before processing inputs.  If I get any better ideas, I'll come back to this and update it.

Comment: The obvious way to address the A* issue is to not require it to be a shortest path, but then you have to balance path length vs dictionary queries in the score, which is going to be messy.

Comment: About "dictionary lookup"... check if a word in the dictionary using a black-box function seems good enough. Hopefully it won't make programs take awfully long time to run. / Restrict to `a-z`? Adding Unicode would be impossible to guess.

Answer (score 1):

#### Objective

Given a 2D array (of x by x size), write a program or function to alternatively shift elements of the array along the anti-diagonals. (anti-diagonals are right to left, top to bottom). (first anti-diagonal moves down second anti-diagonal moves up with elements wrapping when they reach the end of the anti-diagonal)

#### Example

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

Will become:

```
a e i g
b c j n
f m h o
d k l p
```

I will follow the tradition of selecting the shortest working code as the best answer

**edited for user202729 suggestion

Comment: Should it be "antidiagonals"?

Comment: [Dupe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63755/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor im trying to shift the anti-diagonals not reverse them

Comment: So is the question I linked.

Comment: @PeterTaylor look at the 4x4 test case and compare it with mine. I have a different result for that case. I am asking people to shift the elements along the anti diagonals, not to rotate the anti diagonals themselves.

Comment: Although the specification of this proposal is not especially clear, I think that the only difference is that the question I linked rotates all anti-diagonals in the same direction whereas this rotates them alternately in one direction and the other.

Comment: @PeterTaylor i will again clarify i am not rotating them i am shifting them. for example if an anti diagonal was say - 1 2 3 4 5 6 my outcome would be: 6 1 2 3 4 5 (or 2 3 4 5 6 1 depending on which antidiagonal it was) instead of 6 5 4 3 2 1 (which is the rotation of that antidiagonal)

Comment: Shifting and rotating are different words for the same thing: the only difference is that *rotating* makes it clearer that it wraps round rather than losing one element from one end and introducing a new one at the other end. You're thinking of *reversal*.

Comment: @peter Taylor your right... I goofed up while matching the arrays thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

## What's in an ISBN?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given an ISBN-10 code starting with `0` or `1`, extract the registration group, registrant, publication, and checksum numbers.

### Background

We've talked about [International Standard Book Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) before, including [converting them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153624/converting-isbn-13-to-isbn-10#153624) and [calculating their checksums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/342/calculate-isbn-13-check-digit). Now let's talk about parsing their data.

An ISBN-10 code has four parts; in order from left to right: registration
group, registrant, publication, and checksum. We're only going to consider registration group numbers `0` and `1`, which represent English-speaking areas. Take a look at these two ISBN-10 codes, shown with their parts separated:

- `0-307-45547-5` – This book, from registration group `0`, is printed by publishing giant Penguin Random House. Penguin prints thousands of books, so it's assigned ISBN blocks with few digits for registrar (`307` here), leaving many digits for publication (`45547`). The checksum is `5`.
- `1-940696-27-5` – This book, from registration group `1`, is printed by indie poetry press Wave Books, which prints just a few books each year, so its ISBN blocks have many digits for registrant (`940696` here) and just a few for publication number (`27`). The checksum is also `5`.

### Specification

Write a program or function that takes a non-separated ISBN-10 code and return its four parts as distinct values.

ISBN-10 codes in registration groups `0` and `1` are separated according to the following scheme, where `xx…` is registrant number and `y` is checksum.

```
From            to                 From            to
-------------   -------------      -------------   -------------
0-00-xxxxxx-y … 0-19-xxxxxx-y      1-00-xxxxxx-y … 1-09-xxxxxx-y
0-200-xxxxx-y … 0-699-xxxxx-y      1-100-xxxxx-y … 1-399-xxxxx-y
0-7000-xxxx-y … 0-8499-xxxx-y      1-4000-xxxx-y … 1-5499-xxxx-y
0-85000-xxx-y … 0-89999-xxx-y      1-55000-xxx-y … 1-86979-xxx-y
0-900000-xx-y … 0-949999-xx-y      1-869800-xx-y … 1-998999-xx-y
0-9500000-x-y … 0-9999999-x-y      1-9990000-x-y … 1-9999999-x-y
```

For example, `0307455475` lies in the range `0-200-xxxxx-y … 0-699-xxxxx-y`, so we know it has three digits for registrant and five for publication and the program, given this input, should return `0`, `307`, `45547`, and `5`.

Likewise, `1940696275` is in the range `1-869800-xx-y … 1-998999-xx-y`, so the program should return `1`, `940696`, `27`, and `5`.

#### Input

- Input may be in any convenient format, e.g. a string, list of characters, or list of numbers.
- The input must be 10 or fewer characters or numbers, plus an optional trailing newline. Leading zeroes are optional.
- In ISBN-10 codes the checksum 10 is represented with an `X`. If your
  program takes input as a list of numbers, the number `10` may be used. If it takes input as a string or list of characters, a *single* non-digit character of your choosing (e.g. `X` or `x`) must be used.
- Otherwise, standard input rules apply.

#### Output

- Output may be in any convenient format, as long as each part is easily distinguishable from the next, e.g. a delimited string, a list of four numbers, or a list of four lists of numbers.
- Leading zeroes are optional.
- If the checksum is 10, it may be `10` (as a number or string) or a single non-digit character of your choosing. For example, both `0 8044 2957 X` and `0 8044 2957 10` are valid.
- Otherwise, standard output rules apply.

### Winning

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); the solution with the fewest bytes wins.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Test cases

```
Input       Output
0000000000  0-00-000000-0
0144751605  0-14-475160-5
0393765621  0-393-76562-1
0763320041  0-7633-2004-1
0859056018  0-85905-601-8
0906789222  0-906789-22-2
0958171947  0-9581719-4-7
0999999999  0-9999999-9-9
099999999X  0-9999999-9-X
1000000000  1-00-000000-0
1080925818  1-08-092581-8
1149092167  1-149-09216-7
1457721261  1-4577-2126-1
1578424693  1-57842-469-3
1973088617  1-973088-61-7
1999973361  1-9999733-6-1
1999999999  1-9999999-9-9
199999999X  1-9999999-9-X
```

> ### Sandbox questions
>
> 1. What are good tags for this?
> 2. Is the description of the separation scheme clear?
> 3. Any test cases missing (or wrong)?

Answer (score 1):

## Shape sequence sums

#### 0. DEFINITIONS

For the purposes of this challenge, a *sequence* refers to a list of numbers whose absolute values increment in steps of 1. A sequence begins with a value of 1, 0, or -1.
A *positive sequence* refers to the natural numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on.
A *negative sequence* refers to the additive inverses of the natural numbers: -1, -2, -3, -4, and so on.

#### 1. CHALLENGE

Given an integer `n`, return a list of sequences such that the sum of all the numbers in the list is equal to `n`. Sequences must alternate in sign (see test cases). Solutions must produce the list with the fewest sequences; that is, the sign should change a minimal number of times. (Read: Don't do 1, 2, -1 over and over again.) The resulting list must be flat, not nested. The shortest working solution wins.

#### 2. TEST CASES

```
 17: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, -3, 1, 2, -1
 18: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2
 19: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, 1
 21: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
-21: -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6
 -5: -1, -2, -3, 1
  0: 0 or [] (null set)
```

You may choose to begin each sequence with 0 instead of 1 or -1. However, if you do this, *every* sequence must begin with a zero, not just the positives, the negatives, the first sequence, or any other strict subset. This also means that input 0 requires a list containing a single 0.

```
 17: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 2, 0, -1
  0: 0
```

[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Is there any requirement that answers provide an output with the smallest number of sequences, the fewest total numbers, or just any list of numbers which can be partitioned into alternating positive and negative sequences? I might recommend some restriction else repeating `1, 2, -1` will eventually reach any number

Comment: Can the output for `0` be `[]`, ie. is the empty sequence a sequence?

Comment: @Kamil & BMO: Thanks, I've updated to address these. Also added requirement that list be flat.

Comment: Why do you require flatness?

Comment: Idk, I just feel like it. I like flat lists :P

Comment: Title suggestion: "Shape sequence sums"

Comment: 1. I think that this question would be a lot simpler to understand if it were rewritten in terms of triangle numbers rather than sequences. 2. Most of the test cases are wrong. Every integer can be produced with just two sequences.

Answer (score 1):

## Implement RaGOL [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

RaGOL (**Ra**ndom **G**ame **o**f **L**ife) is a randomized cellular automaton based on GOL (**G**ame **o**f **L**ife). For reference, here are the rules of GOL (B3/S23):

- Moore neighborhoods are used, that is, a cell `#` looks at its neighbors `*` as in here:

  ```
  .......
  .......
  ..***..
  ..*#*..
  ..***..
  .......
  .......
  ```
- A cell can have 2 states: **dead** or **alive**
- If a **dead** cell has 3 **alive** neighbors, it becomes **alive**.
- If an **alive** cell does not have exactly 2 or 3 **alive** neighbors, it becomes **dead**.

In this challenge, we will assume the board is unbounded, and the default state of a cell is **dead**.

However, since [we have already implemented GOL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3434/41024), it's time to change the rules a bit. Here are the differences between GOL and RaGOL:

- If a **dead** cell has 3 **alive** neighbors, there is 1/3 of a chance it becomes **alive**.
- If an **alive** cell has 2 **alive** neighbors, there is 1/5 of a chance it becomes **dead**.
- If an **alive** cell has 3 **alive** neighbors, there are 2/5 of a chance it becomes **dead**.

Note that if an **alive** cell doesn't have exactly 2 or 3 **alive** neighbors, it still becomes **dead** just like in GOL.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to get an ***x*×*y*** RaGOL board ***B*** where ***x* > 0** and ***y* > 0** and a number ***N* > 0** and return the board after ***N*** generations starting from ***B***.

Please note that the result isn't deterministic.

You will also need to expand the board to simulate an unbounded-board automaton in some cases.

## Rules

- You can get ***B*** and ***N*** in any reasonable way.
- Errors due to floating-point imprecision do not matter, be it a slight difference due to how floats work or a precision limit of the float datatype you use. Otherwise, you must adhere to the aforementioned probabilities.
- You may expand the board as much as you like, as long as 1) the result will be theoretically returned at some point in time and 2) the whole expected result is shown.

  - Note: If your language has a board datatype which natively supports unbounded boards, you can use that instead of manually expanding the resulting board, as long as the correct result is returned sometime. You may also use third-party modules which provide such a datatype, or even implement your own, just as long as there is an implementation available online!

Comment: I expect Stencil to win on this one.

Comment: @Adám Sure, that could very well be the case, but what is the problem exactly? Of course some types of challenges are better answered by languages made especially for them, however should we stop posting challenges altogether? ;)

Comment: It wasn't intended as a criticism.

Comment: Have you tried making a reference implementation? The rules tend to cause extinction. I think changing the chances to 2/3, 3/5, 4/5 works better.

Comment: @Adám I may change the ratios, yeah. I haven't yet gotten around to making a reference implementation.

Comment: [Here you go.](https://tio.run/##Ky5JzUvOzPn/XyNRwVFTI0nBSVMjWcFZ81HbBA1DBWNNIGGqqWEEJBQedbcoFNsY26ZaJdrZO4K4xY86lhsB@Ul29k5QLkg62c7eGcg1@P/f0Nbe0EDB0OBR7xajf/kFJZn5ecX/jTwB "Stencil – Try It Online") ***N*** is in the Command-line option. The ratio settings should be obvious.

Comment: @Adám Uh, I was planning to make it myself, but thanks! EDIT: Hm, looks like the implementation is a little bit wrong...maybe [this](https://tio.run/##Ky5JzUvOzPn/XyNRwVFTI0nBSVMjWcFZ81HbBA1DBWNNIGGqqWEEJBQedbcoFNsY26ZaJT7qXGrvCBIoftSx3AgokgQScYIKgJQkgwScgQIG//8b2tobGigYGjzq3WL0L7@gJDM/r/i/kScA) fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

### Code Basketball

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Programs are competing in a game of "basketball". They are given a 5x6 (Minus the top center character)
grid on which to put either `/`, `\`, or `^`. The programs can place two symbols every tick on the grid. If the programs try and place a symbol at the same place at the same time, neither symbol is placed.

On the first tick, a 'ball', `o`, is spawned at (3,6) on the grid. The ball falls by one character every tick. If the ball encounters a \ while falling, it moves to the right. If it encounters a /, it moves to the left. If the ball hits a ^, it moves back to the top of the grid at that x position. The ball only moves once every tick, and does not effect the map on it's own.

When the ball is on the bottom row, if it's on the left, it gives a point to the first program and respawns, if it's on the right, it gives a point to the second program and respawns. If it's in the center, it simply respawns without giving points to anyone.

If the ball tries to move off the map, it simply stays in place.

The grid is rotated when transfered to the contending programs so that it always appears that the left is that program's goal.

### Program I/O

Programs use Standard Input and Standard Output to communicate to the contest framework. The program is sent a 30 byte buffer containing a map and a 2 byte buffer containing the position of the ball.

The program must send two 3 byte buffers in response with the character to put on the map, it's x position, and it's y position.

The framework gives each program 5 seconds to perform there action. If they fail to be within this 5 second window three times, they automatically lose to prevent the round from going on too long.

### Competition

Programs will compete in pairs of two. The winner of each pair will move on to the next round, and be paired up with another winner.

> Sandbox questions
>
> 1. How can this be improved?
> 2. What actions should I take to make sure rounds are fair?
> 3. How should invalid data be handled when sent to the framework?

Comment: The execution of time is unclear here:  What happens if a ball falls down on the following line: `\\\\\ ` ?  Does it move all the way across in a single move or does each step take a single move?  Does the ball remove symbols that it hit?

Comment: I think your IO is a bit cumbersome:  Simply feed them all of the info at the start, and wait for them to output the two new symbols.

Comment: I'll clear that up. The ball will move across one step at a time. Symbols are not removed, to prevent it from being the same thing each round.

Comment: More questions: What happens if both programs place on the same square?  If the ball is currently on a `\ ` and I place a `/` on the square it currently is on, which action does it follow?

Comment: Cleared that up as well. The write is canceled out. In terms of the ball, it follows the new symbol the next tick.

Comment: Just making sure I understand:  If two players write on the same square, nothing happens.  If a ball is on (3,6) and the square is a `/ `, but I write a `\ `, the ball won't be affected, because my symbol only affects things the next tick.

Comment: Finally, (and the issue I don't see easily resolved):  I feel like this has a *really* small search space, and very little room for different strategies.  Technically, there are 7830 moves a turn, but most of the squares and moves are irrelevant and can be ignored.  In essence, this game feels like a tug-of-war where both sides are equally as strong.  Any push to the right is easily countered by a push to the left.

Comment: Precisely. The programs make their changes after the ball has made it's move for that tick.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I've been thinking that too. The grid space can be fairly easily expanded.  The game is a game of "skill" between the two programs. They (The programmers) have to try and be inventive to force intresting situations and possibly win. If i do expand the grid space, how large should it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72739/discussion-between-moonheart08-and-nathan-merrill).

Answer (score 1):

## Basketball Recruitment [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

You're recruiting your local neighborhood for your Jr Basketball team.  However, the opposing team also is recruiting!

- You both stand at the end of the street of 100 houses.  Each house has a kid with a unique, random height from 1 to 100. Taller is better.
- **Actions take different amounts of time.**  Your opponent may have a different turn order, or may even have more/less turns than you.
- If you have spent less than or equal time than your opponent, then your turn is next (turns can be simultaneous)

On your turn you perform one of the following actions:

- **Recruit** the kid at the `N`th house.  This takes `N` Time.

  - If you both recruit the same kid, you get into argument, and he decides not to play basketball this year.  (Nobody gets him)
  - Once recruited, a kid won't switch sides.
- **Disqualify** the kid at the `N`th house.  There are myriads of rules to Jr Basketball, and you know just which rules he's breaking.  This takes `10` time.

  - You cannot disqualify a kid that has been recruited or is in the process of recruitment.
  - If you try to disqualify a kid on the same turn your opponent tries to recruit him, the disqualification fails.

After all of the boys have been recruited, been disqualified, or lost interest, we play the big game:

1. We place the teams into two lines from shortest to tallest.
2. Each pair of boys play each other.
3. The taller one wins, and gives his team 1 point.
4. If a team has more boys than the other, they get 1 point for each extra boy.
5. The team with the most points wins.

Now, your goal is to become the top recruiter.  This means you need to win as many games as possible.  You will face many other recruiters at random until a clear victor is decided.

Comment: what happens if you recruit more people than your opponent?

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to add that to the post.  Thanks!

Comment: One thing I immediately notice is that recruiting more boys can be detrimental, if they're not as good as some other boys on the team: example: team 1: 3 5 7 9 11 vs team 2: 2 4 6 8 10. team 1 recruiting a boy of height 1 would cause team 1 to lose

Comment: That sounds like a feature, not a problem :)

Comment: I didn't say it was a problem, it was an observation. maybe i should have been clearer

Answer (score 1):

## Convert Arabic Numbers to Chinese Numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

> **There EXISTS a similar question, ["Convert Chinese numbers"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97734/convert-chinese-numbers), but the question itself differs from that question by:**
>
> 1. That question asks for a shortest code converting Chinese numbers to Arabic numbers, but this asks for a shortest code converting in the opposite direction.
> 2. That question limits the range of `1 <= N < 10^3`, but this has the range far larger than that -- `1 <= N < 10^8192`.
> 3. Due to the range of that question, that question only considers one type of representation on Chinese numbers, but this considers four -- the commonly used *Wan Jin* (萬進) and other ancient systems. These terms will be explained in the introduction part.
>
> **There EXISTS another similar question ["Convert a number to Korean"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155995/convert-a-number-to-korean), but there is essential difference because Korean number only uses *Wan Jin*, always omits "一(일)"s before "十(십)"s, "百(백)"s and "千(천)"s and all "零"s between digits, and so does Japanese.**

**Sandbox**

> - I have edited the challenge description so that the rules are now outlining the process of conversion. Although this will be clearer in illustrating the rules, will this be restricting the choice of algorithms?

### Introduction

Chinese numbers, literally, is the number still in use in societies which uses Chinese characters. Although Arabic numbers are also in use nowadays, Chinese numbers still have an important role.

The system Chinese people in Taiwan are using is called *Wan Jin* (萬進), which names `1,000,000,000,000` (1 trillion) as *Yi Zhao* (一兆). However, according to *Wu Jing Suan Shu* (五經算術) ,in the history there existed 3 different kinds of such large-number representations. The reference says:

> 按黃帝為法，數有十等。及其用也，乃有三焉。十等者，謂「億、兆、京、垓、秭、壤、溝、澗、正、載」也。三等者，謂「上、中、下」也。其下數者，十十變之。若言十萬曰億，十億曰兆，十兆曰京也。中數者，萬萬變之。若言萬萬曰億，萬萬億曰兆，萬萬兆曰京也。上數者，數窮則變。若言萬萬曰億，億億曰兆、兆兆曰京也。
>
> (Translation) According to Huang Di, there are 10 "ranks" of numbers. Regarding the usages, there are three. The 10 ranks are called *Yì* (億), *Zhào* (兆), *Jīng* (京), *Gāi* (垓), *Zǐ* (秭), *Ráng* (穰), *Gōu* (溝), *Jiàn* (澗), *Zhèng* (正), *Zài* (載). The three usages are called "Upper", "Middle" and "Lower". For the "Lower", the rank changes if multiplied by 10. We call 10 *Wàn* as *Yì*, 10 *Yì* as *Zhào*, and 10 *Zhào* as *Jīng*. For the "Middle", the rank changes if multiplied by 100,000,000. We call 100,000,000 *Wàn* as *Yì*, 100,000,000 *Yì* as *Zhào*, and 100,000,000 *Zhào* as *Jīng*. And for the "Upper", the rank changes if the rank exhausts its numbers. We call 1 *Wàn* *Wàn* as *Yì*, 1 *Yì* *Yì* as *Zhào*, and 1 *Zhào* *Zhào* as *Jīng*.

To sum up, we have 4 systems which is, or was in use in Chinese history:

- *Xia Shu* (下數): Starting from *wan* (萬, `10,000`), the rank changes by multipling by 10. 10 *wan* is called *yi* (億, `100,000`), 10 *yi* is called *zhao* (兆, `1,000,000`), 10 *zhao* is called *jing* (京, `10,000,000`), etc.
- *Zhong Shu* (中數): Starting from *wan* (萬, `10,000`), the rank changes by multipling by 10<sup>8</sup>, with the exception of *yi*, which represents `10^8`. 10,000 *wan* is called *yi* (億, `10^8`), 10<sup>8</sup> *yi* is called *zhao* (兆, `10^16`), 10<sup>8</sup> *zhao* is called *jing* (京, `10^24`), etc.
- *Shang Shu* (上數): Starting from *wan* (萬, `10,000`), the rank changes by squaring. 10,000 *wan* is called *yi* (億, `10^8`), 10<sup>8</sup> *yi* is called *zhao* (兆, `10^16`), 10<sup>16</sup> *zhao* is called *jing* (京, `10^32`), etc.
- *Wan Jin* (萬進): Starting from *wan* (萬, `10,000`), the rank changes by multipling by 10,000. 10,000 *wan* is called *yi* (億, `10^8`), 10,000 *yi* is called *zhao* (兆, `10^12`), 10,000 *zhao* is called *jing* (京, `10^16`), etc.

**Table 1: Rank markers in Chinese numbers**

```
 Name    Wan Jin      Xia Shu      Zhong Shu   Shang Shu
(十               commonly representing 10^1            )
(百               commonly representing 10^2            )
(千               commonly representing 10^3            )
(萬               commonly representing 10^4            )
 億      10^8         10^5         10^8        10^8
 兆      10^12        10^6         10^16       10^16
 京      10^16        10^7         10^24       10^32
 垓      10^20        10^8         10^32       10^64
 秭      10^24        10^9         10^40       10^128
 穰      10^28        10^10        10^48       10^256
 溝      10^32        10^11        10^56       10^512
 澗      10^36        10^12        10^64       10^1024
 正      10^40        10^13        10^72       10^2048
 載      10^44        10^14        10^80       10^4096
```

For numbers smaller than 10, this works as

```
零:0 一:1 二:2 三:3 四:4 五:5 六:6 七:7 八:8 九:9
```

### Challenge

In this challenge, you are required to write the shortest code, accepting two inputs: the number N, and a number S indicating the system used, converts N into the corresponding Chinese representation according to the given system, and output the representation. Here are some basic rules about converting Chinese numbers:

> For numbers less than 10,000 and *Xia Shu* numbers:
>
> 1. Append position markers digit by digit first.
>
>    - `1234 => 一千二百三十四`
>    - `1234567 => 一兆二億三萬四千五百六十七`
> 2. Strip away all position markers prepended by "零", coalesce all consecutive "零"s into a single "零", and remove the leading/trailing "零"s.
>
>    - `5 => 五`, `25 => 二十五`, `125 => 一百二十五`
>    - `20 => 二十`, `100 => 一百`, `5000 => 五千`.
>    - `1001 => 一千零一`
>
> For *Wan Jin* numbers:
>
> 1. Divide the digits into subgroups of at most 4 digits each from the right.
>
>    - `12345678900004321 => 1'2345'6789'0000'4321`
> 2. Apply to each subgroup the conversion for numbers less than 10,000 (as above), and append each subgroup with the corresponding rank markers. If there is any "0" at the subgroup boundary, append "零" after the rank marker.
>
>    - `1'2345'6789'0000'4321 => (一)京(二千三百四十五)兆(六千七百八十九)億零(零)萬零(四千三百二十一)`
> 3. Discard the subgroups with "零", together with their rank markers, and remove redundant "零"s.
>
>    - `(一)京(二千三百四十五)兆(六千七百八十九)億零(零)萬零(四千三百二十一) => 一京二千三百四十五兆六千七百八十九億零四千三百二十一`
>
> For *Zhong Shu* numbers:
>
> 1. Divide the digits into subgroups of at most 8 digits each from the right.
>
>    - `12345678900004321 => 1"23456789"00004321`
> 2. Apply to each subgroup the conversion for *Wan Jin* numbers (as above), and append each subgroup with the corresponding rank markers. If there is any "0" at the subgroup boundary, append "零" after the rank marker.
>
>    - `1"23456789"00004321 => (一)兆(二千三百四十五萬六千七百八十九)億零(四千三百二十一)`
> 3. Discard the subgroups with "零", together with their rank markers, and remove redundant "零"s.
>
>    - `(一)兆(二千三百四十五萬六千七百八十九)億零(四千三百二十一) => 一兆二千三百四十五萬六千七百八十九億零四千三百二十一`
>
> For *Shang Shu* numbers:
>
> 1. Divide the digits into 2 subgroups: the least significant one with number of digits equals to the least power of 2 not less than half of the original length, and the most significant one with the remaining digits.
>
>    - `123456789012345678901234567890 => (12345678901234)(5678901234567890)`
> 2. Append the most significant subgroup with the corresponding rank marker. If there is any "0" at the subgroup boundary, append "零" after the rank marker.
>
>    - `(12345678901234)(5678901234567890) => 12345678901234兆5678901234567890`
> 3. Discard the subgroups with "零", together with their rank markers
> 4. Recursively apply all steps to each subgroup with a lower rank marker, until the number of digits in a subgroup is less than 4, which then apply the conversion for numbers less than 10,000 (as above).
>
>    - `12345678901234兆5678901234567890 => 123456億78901234兆56789012億34567890 => 12萬3456億7890萬零1234兆5678萬9012億3456萬7890 => 十二萬三千四百五十六億七千八百九十萬零一千二百三十四兆五千六百七十八萬九千零一十二億三千四百五十六萬七千八百九十`
>
> And at last...
>
> 1. If "一十" is at the beginning, remove the "一".
>
>    - `15 => 十五`
>    - `114514 => 十一萬四千五百一十四`, `10011 => 一萬零一十一`.
> 2. Remove redundant "零"s, and if an empty string occurs, return with "零".

For more details, the reference implementation in JSFiddle gives the reference code.

### Requirements

- Your code must be a full program or a function. Defining helper functions are allowed. Snippets are not allowed.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed by default.
- You can use any methods of I/O that are considered "standard" by PPCG community.
- You must receive 2 inputs, one number N, and one number S. You can pass the inputs as strings or as integers. Please indicate your choice.
- You may assume the input is always valid, i.e. `S in [0, 1, 2, 3]` and `N` is within the corresponding range:

**Table 2: Number systems and their representable number range**

```
S (System)       N (Number Range)
0 (Wan Jin)      1 <= N < 1E+48
1 (Xia Shu)      1 <= N < 1E+15
2 (Zhong Shu)    1 <= N < 1E+88
3 (Shang Shu)    1 <= N < 1E+8192
```

- In case Unicode is not supported by the interpreter and/or the language, or for any reasons, you may use one of the two Chinese Pinyins in place of the corresponding Chinese characters as output as follows. Your choice must be consistent over all outputs. One space must be added between the pinyins of 2 characters. You must indicate if you choose to do so.

**Table 3: The Chinese characters and their pinyin representations**

```
Character  Pinyin              Character  Pinyin
一         yī or yi1           二         èr or er4
三         sān or san3         四         sì or si4
五         wǔ or wu3           六         liù or liu4
七         qī or qi1           八         bā or ba1
九         jiǔ or jiu3         十         shí or shi2
百         bǎi or bai3         千         qiān or qian1
萬         wàn or wan4         億         yì or yi4
兆         zhào or zhao4       京         jīng or jing1
垓         gāi or gai1         秭         zǐ or zi3
穰         ráng or rang2       溝         gōu or gou1
澗         jiàn or jian4       正         zhèng or zheng4
載         zài or zai4         零         líng or ling2
```

### Example I/O (Only the first Pinyin format is displayed)

In these examples, I use `' => 萬, " => 億, (...) => 兆, [...] => 京, {...} => 垓, <...> => 秭` in the grouping for clarity. The grouping is only for illustration, and you do not need to print the groupings.

```
Input:    18446744073709551616 0
Grouping: [1844](6744)0737"0955'1616
Output:   一千八百四十四京六千七百四十四兆零七百三十七億零九百五十五萬一千六百一十六
    or    yī qiān bā bǎi sì shí sì jīng liù qiān qī bǎi sì shí sì zhào líng qī bǎi sān shí qī yì líng jiǔ bǎi wǔ shí wǔ wàn yī qiān liù bǎi yī shí liù

Input:    1234567890 1
Grouping: <1>{2}[3](4)5"6'7890
Output:   一秭二垓三京四兆五億六萬七千八百九十
    or    yī zǐ èr gāi sān jīng sì zhào wǔ yì liù wàn qī qiān bā bǎi jiǔ shí

Input:    1267650600228229401496703205376 2
Grouping: [126'7650](6002'2822)9401'4967"0320'5376
Output:   一百二十六萬七千六百五十京零六千零二萬二千八百二十二兆九千四百零一萬四千九百六十七億零三百二十萬零五千三百七十六
    or    yī bǎi èr shí liù wàn qī qiān liù bǎi wǔ shí jīng líng liù qiān líng èr  wàn èr qiān bā bǎi èr shí èr zhào jiǔ qiān sì bǎi líng yī wàn sì qiān jiǔ bǎi liù shí qī yì líng sān bǎi èr shí wàn líng wǔ qiān sān bǎi qī shí liù

Input:    8749002899132047697490008908470485461412677723572849745703082425639811996797503692894052708092215296 3
Grouping: {[8749](0028'9913"2047'6974)9000'8908"4704'8546}[(1412'6777"2357'2849)7457'0308"2425'6398](1199'6797"5036'9289)4052'7080"9221'5296
Output  : 八千七百四十九京零二十八萬九千九百一十三億二千零四十七萬六千九百七十四兆九千萬零八千九百零八億四千七百零四萬八千五百四十六垓一千四百一十二萬六千七百七十七億二千三百五十七萬二千八百四十九兆七千四百五十七萬零三百零八億二千四百二十五萬六千三百九十八京一千一百九十九萬六千七百九十七億五千零三十六萬九千二百八十九兆四千零五十二萬七千零八十億零九千二百二十一萬五千二百九十六
    or    bā qiān qī bǎi sì shí jiǔ jīng líng èr shí bā wàn jiǔ qiān jiǔ bǎi yī shí sān yì èr qiān líng sì shí qī wàn liù qiān jiǔ bǎi qī shí sì zhào jiǔ qiān wàn líng bā qiān jiǔ bǎi líng bā yì sì qiān qī bǎi líng sì wàn bā qiān wǔ bǎi sì shí liù gāi yī qiān sì bǎi yī shí èr wàn liù qiān qī bǎi qī shí qī yì èr qiān sān bǎi wǔ shí qī wàn èr qiān bā bǎi sì shí jiǔ zhào qī qiān sì bǎi wǔ shí qī wàn líng sān bǎi líng bā yì èr qiān sì bǎi èr shí wǔ wàn liù qiān sān bǎi jiǔ shí bā jīng yī qiān yī bǎi jiǔ shí jiǔ wàn liù qiān qī bǎi jiǔ shí qī yì wǔ qiān líng sān shí liù wàn jiǔ qiān èr bǎi bā shí jiǔ zhào sì qiān líng wǔ shí èr wàn qī qiān líng bā shí yì líng jiǔ qiān èr bǎi èr shí yī wàn wǔ qiān èr bǎi jiǔ shí liù
```

[Here is a reference implementation in JS, not golfed at all](https://jsfiddle.net/kaoqr3ma/2/)

### Winning Criteria

As this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code measuring in bytes wins. Accented Latin alphabets and Chinese characters must be measured in UTF-8 unless they are included in the SBCS of the language and can be used in the string literals.

### Reference

[Wikipedia - 中文數字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97#%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%B8%E7%B3%BB%E7%B5%B1)

Comment: I think you should also add an explanation for numbers less than 10,000. What's even 1, 2, 3, ...?

Comment: @wastl Added back details about 0~9. For numbers less than 10,000, *Xia Shu* algorithm applies

Comment: no example for `coalesce all consecutive "零"s into a single "零"`, e.g. 4002

Comment: what is the result of `WanJin(10010)`? 一萬零一十? 一萬零十?

Comment: @tsh Added. and `WanJin(10010)` should be 一萬零一十 because the 一十 is not at the beginning. (一萬零十 should be something in like dialect?) There is an example of `WanJin(10011)` though

Comment: @user71546 The example is for XiaShu(10011), not WanJin(10011).

Comment: Oh I should indicate that the replacement is only at the final step.

Comment: @tsh Grouped the removal of redundant "零"s and removal of leading "一" before "十" at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

## Assemble an XOISC program

**Tags**: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parentheses), [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

---

Recently I solved [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154617/design-a-one-instruction-set-computer) challenge, for which I created [XOISC](https://github.com/bforte/XOISC) - a very low-level functional language. To compile a program (written in the absurdly high-level lambda calculus programming language) it must first be translated into an expression consisting only of *X* combinators and from there it can be translated to the "machine language".

There's an initially empty stack and the program only consists of a stream of integers. For each integer the following happens:

Pop *N* elements *f<sub>1</sub>,...,f<sub>N</sub>* and push *X (f<sub>1</sub> (..(f<sub>N-1</sub> f<sub>N</sub>)..))* - ie. it right-folds function application and applies this to another *X*.

Eventually we'll end up with a stack of functions which gets left-folded with function application. That's it.

### How does it work?

When parsing such an expression, one thing to keep in mind is that function application is left-associative - meaning that *X (X X) X* is read as *(X (X X)) X* rather than *X ((X X) X)*.

If we have an expression *f g* with sub-expressions *f* and *g* (in the code below `App f g` - eg. *X (X X) X* would be *f = X (X X)* and *g = X*), there's a simple recursive algorithm to assemble it:

```hs
-- Base case: We simply need to pop the accumulated functions 
asm' n X         = [n]
-- Recurse: First build the left function, then the right one. 
--          Incrementing n ensures that we leave (f g) on stack
asm' n (App f g) = asm' 0 f ++ asm' (n+1) g

-- Now we start with 0 functions on the stack:
asm expr = asm' 0 expr
```

For those unfamiliar with Haskell:

- this algorithm assumes an already parsed expression in the form of of a binary tree (the definition of the data structure would be `data Exp = X | App Exp Exp` where `X` would be a leaf and `App f g` would be a node with children `f` and `g` that are `Exp`s as well)<sup>*</sup>
- `asm' n exp` does a case distinction by matching a pattern on `exp`:

  - if the expression is *X* (ie. `exp = X`) it's the base case and just returns a singleton list containing `n` (an integer)
  - else it's of the form *f g* (with *f,g* some sub-expressions) which is expressed as `App f g`, so it will recursively build the list for *f* and append the list of *g*
- to assemble an expression `exp` we begin initialize the recursive algorithm with `n = 0` (`asm' 0 exp`)

**Note**: Since a lot of people here know Python, you can find a horrible but very well documented Python reference implementation [here](https://tio.run/##jVTvi5tAEP3uXzHcQdXenk3Sb4EclHLQfiiUfgqIlE0ya2zXVXY3d5eW/u3prKtGTa5UwR87zxnnzdtXH@2@Uu9Ppx0KkCjsd25MtS24xQhfahMvA6Dj5uYGvnKNyu7RFL8QKKbRmKJSBt6AOWzuBysMjE2AoEfQKCRubZPEHRssVN4Uuu8KFU@YwOMLL2uJZtkjAdJZBvcP7jZaZHT6gHvO2DTcrXaQ5v06zAF9uAd3X3eBADoCgubhFmbv1oP2oTDjdnAHXGrkuyPRUMEzwo@DsUSEPWhCeyoKAfZYtxS7FIWy59ZbrAt2RT9yg5CKOQOxYJAkSbaEb7g9aFqmnxBzmoJYAFc7qIdzonvZVZSo2oIPsDhXEwxyBm81lrDyNbuI5IKWJqoQ8SCeX8bzeNrHBJCmlJe5j4n2OwKVcdflF/4TSUwaiUI5VRVQX5dUG2JYymBQLp3KOAZRaUDiuGkvC4LAqZ14MhgZq12Nsc6JVK6GQyYU6ZbR0qVM15ciXTfnKxJdQ0TR2H/Vq@wivP6Xfj3Iwc65rqt3rN1PldbFRh7Baq4M0VISK/XBgq2AQ7SvahQHKY8xfG2MAWRhvGIdhZzBxrGYhlEaMgjjzF2Buet6FmZnVlpWSR3tU6KxlnyLkcvRz/vxiUsn0aYMKbjs51/Y0O8rOA87eF1TSImiMP39JwsT1xW3/WDjuJ03N6WTv2agVrPBvD8Yg@VG0si9JHbDwefkTsqpjDf/eF0B141q5EMzNmfzafj6uAbxbvJtihlb/EeSHjwnOH1yIYLPouF87GGpYHlG7J4tBZ4Lu3dc0WAcE927upu3iSJVWVz6AaLKKUqJuHzmRwMLR9UWa9soZ1JvTQucJtzm6e3CAci7/L7u6LyFeOqZuvHMRjTO8Vpjo9XVaups3tP01JOcGERM9uMecubbikc2opxR3JLL8p3fJMzrg7RJjPBONeToNZmDjVwm7ykNOiLlxafTZKf@BQ) which does the parsing as well as the assembling!

---

<sup>*</sup> The `|` means that an `Exp` type can be constructed of either the left constructor (`X`) or of the right one (`App Exp Exp` where the two `Exp` are `Exp` two sub-expressions).

For example the expression *X (X X) X* would be expressed as `App (App X (App X X)) X`.

### Example

Having an expression *X (X X) X*, it helps to think of the implicit parentheses: *(X (X X)) X*

Translating this with the above algorithm:

- Assemble *(X (X X))*:

  - Assemble *X*:

    - Base case => `0`
  - Now Assemble *X X*, making sure it gets applied to the previous one (+1)

    - The first *X* gives us a `0`
    - The second one gives us `0 + 1 + 1 = 2` (apply to *X* and previous one)
- So the left *(X (X X))* gave us `[0,0,2]`, assembling the right *X*:

  - This gives us `0 + 1` (apply to the previous one)

And we end up with the program `[0,0,2,1]`.

**Note**: While this algorithm ensures that there's a program for every expression, there can be other solutions too. For example `[0,0,1,0]` would be a valid one for *X (X X) X* as well.

### Challenge

Given an expression consisting of *X* combinators, translate it to the XOISC machine language:

- Input will be a string encoding such an expression

  - The input will be a valid expression and non-empty
  - You may choose to require an input string that contains no spaces
  - You may choose the characters encoding parentheses and the combinator itself (as long as it's consistent, eg. using `[`,`]`,`x` instead of `(`,`)`,`X`)
  - You're guaranteed that there are no unnecessary parentheses (eg. `(X X) X` would result in undefined behaviour)
- Output can be a list of integers, a string separated by new-lines or whitespaces

### Testcases

These testcases assume that the input contains whitespaces and choose `X` to encode the combinator.

Note that there may be multiple valid outputs, you're free to choose one<sup>*</sup> - I'll only show the solution resulting from the above algorithm:

```hs
X -> [0]
X X X -> [0,1,1]
X (X X) -> [0,0,2]
X (X X) X -> [0,0,2,1]
X (X (X (X X X))) -> [0,0,0,0,1,4]
X (X X) (X X) (X X) -> [0,0,2,0,2,0,2]
X (X X X (X X)) -> [0,0,1,1,0,3]
X (X (X X) (X X)) -> [0,0,0,2,0,3]
X X (X X (X (X (X (X (X X X)))) X) X) -> [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,2,2]
X (X (X X) X (X X X)) X (X (X (X X) X)) -> [0,0,0,2,1,0,1,3,1,0,0,0,2,3]
X (X (X (X (X X) X X) X X X) X X X X) X X X X X -> [0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1]
X (X (X X (X X) (X X) (X X) X) X (X X) X) X (X X X) X -> [0,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,1,0,2,2,1,0,1,2,1]
```

---

<sup>* [Here](https://tio.run/##XU9BasMwELzrFYNONnGLczXE1JQees7FYExQasUWVWVhLcSH/t3VygRKBEKzszOj3UmFb23ttg2KFD5WjxMa7xPi@4tWCO@bSN@s8dwTwrhAyn1pnKf5nmT3SS9aAIGJjAMUrm8JXHDJ82hPLYXDARKZ5Dcx18Tk8tn8bPnneEjbKJGtFOJHGRfxqOl9dqQdBdT1CX4xjvCK22yH5QjeYi8sxhldH6ts0WpAVeFMUTzipUb36ajP4x9pJ1auARy/OzmlBaFKczzOrs2o2Of21lBD0bWGbevKoiyORdn/AQ)'s a program to validate alternative solutions</sup>

#### Sandbox

- I already [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156566/48198) this to main, but apparently I did a bad job of explaining it.. It's hard to tell what's missing, I'd be happy for feedback (feel free to edit this)!

Comment: I think you need to move away from Haskel syntax and jargon. Just as one example: I have no idea what the point of "Having an expression X (X X) X, it helps to think of the implicit parentheses: (X (X X)) X" is. The whole explanation seems reliant on an understanding of concepts I personally don't usually think about. Also it's confusing having an example as code that is only thinking about the problem in one way and outputting only a single solution of many possible while trying to understand what the possibilities are. Since I can't understand it it is hard for me to help make it clearer :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Thanks a lot for the feedback! It's not necessarily Haskell jargon, but I think I see what you mean. I'll rewrite this completely, it's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

## Generate a maximal binary Gray code

Given an input integer `n`, find an `n`-bit gray code where the sum of the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of bits converted to decimal is maximized.

For example, if `n = 3`, there are 96 possible gray codes, and the maximal sum of deltas in decimal of those is 21. Out of the 96 total, only 8 have maximal deltas.

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 1│
│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 1│
│1 1 0│1 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 1│
│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 1│
│0 1 1│0 1 0│0 0 1│0 0 0│1 1 1│1 1 0│1 0 1│1 0 0│
│1 1 1│1 1 0│1 0 1│1 0 0│0 1 1│0 1 0│0 0 1│0 0 0│
│1 0 1│1 0 0│1 1 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 0 0│0 1 1│0 1 0│
│0 0 1│0 0 0│0 1 1│0 1 0│1 0 1│1 0 0│1 1 1│1 1 0│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Checking the first result, the decimal values are

```
0 4 6 2 3 7 5 1
```

and the deltas of each adjacent pair are

```
4 2 4 1 4 2 4
```

and the sum of that is 21.

### Rules

- The input will be an integer `n > 0`.
- You may output either one or all possible gray codes that satisfy the condition.
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Can we output the decimal values instead of the binary?

Comment: "*the sum of the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of bits converted to decimal*" doesn't make much sense. Decimal is irrelevant (a number's value does not depend on its representation) and mentioning it only serves to make the sentence harder to parse. And looking at the example, it's not about adjacent pairs of bits but adjacent numbers in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## Build a cardinal cyclic quine

A cardinal cyclic quine is a cyclic quine with four states, one for each orientation of the cardinal directions.

See also [Build a half cardinal cyclic quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156913/9365) and [Take a stand against long quine lines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156129/9365).

### Rules

You can decide which rotation you want to implement, clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Once rotated, any gaps in your code should be replaced with spaces to preserve the positioning.

Each program must be unique, you cannot use a quine that has the same layout regardless of orientation.

Your program must satisfy [the community definition of a quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/9365).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest program in each language wins. Your *first* program is used for your byte count.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden.

### Examples

If your program is:

```
$_=q{print};eval
```

Then the next iterations must be either:

```
$
_
=
'
p
r
i
n
t
'
;
e
v
a
l

lave;}tnirp{q=_$

l
a
v
e
;
'
t
n
i
r
p
'
=
_
$
```

or

```
l
a
v
e
;
'
t
n
i
r
p
'
=
_
$

lave;}tnirp{q=_$

$
_
=
'
p
r
i
n
t
'
;
e
v
a
l
```

Or if your program is:

```
;$_=';
;$_=';
print
```

Then the next iterations must be either:

```
;;
''t
==n
__i
$$r
;;p

;'=_$;
;'=_$;
 tnirp

p;;
r$$
i__
n==
t''
 ;;
```

or:

```
p;;
r$$
i__
n==
t''
 ;;

;'=_$;
;'=_$;
 tnirp

;;
''t
==n
__i
$$r
;;p
```

---

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Hope that the source is not a one-line palindrome (specifically, not a palindrome constructed by padding the source with comments)

Comment: ^ Yeah you might want to prevent this by requiring all four programs to be different.

Comment: @MartinEnder I guess my comments here apply to the open question too, but a palindrome with comments probably wouldn't be an optimal solution, so I'm not sure about banning that. I feel that might exclude many languages in which this challenge wouldn't otherwise be possible. Do you think banning them is for the best for the challenge? Can you forsee low-effort answers without banning them?

Comment: @WeijunZhou ^^ :)

Comment: Those cases may be just as well submitted to your existing challenge of half cardinal cyclic quine, and copying answers from your existing challenge to this one is no fun.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Of course. Ok, since that stipulation wasn't added to the original, I'll ensure that's added to this one. Thanks for taking the time to check this out!

Answer (score 1):

## Design a language and golf its interpreter

Your task is to design a language and write an interpreter for it. Your language must have the following properties:

- Its source code will consist of strings of two characters. I will write them as `(` and `)` and refer to them as parentheses, but you can choose whichever two distinct characters you like. You can choose whether to ignore other characters.
- Valid programs will consist of any string in which the parentheses are balanced, such as `()()` or `(()(()()))`. The empty string is a valid program. You may assume the input will be a valid program.
- Programs will take an input and return an output. Valid inputs and outputs are of the same form as source code: they must be balanced strings of parentheses. This input and output may be accomplished by any method you like, e.g. command-line arguments or STDIN/STDOUT. You may assume your program's input will always be valid.
- Your program must be Turing complete. That means that for every computable function from balanced strings to balanced strings, there must be a program in your language that computes it. **Your answer must include a proof of Turing completeness**, otherwise it is not a valid answer.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score will be the size of your interpreter's implementation, measured in bytes. The lowest score wins.

Here are some additional rules and clarifications:

- Your interpreter must be a complete program
- You must include a description of your language's semantics. This is needed in order to prove that it's Turing complete.
- Your interpreter must correctly implement these semantics. (Or at least, it must be able to in principle, given infinite machine resources.) If someone finds a bug in your interpreter, your answer becomes invalid until it's fixed.
- You may not assume numerical types are of unlimited precision unless they actually are - be careful of integer overflow!

Here is the precise grammar for programs as well as input and output strings:

```
<expr> ::= "(" <expr_list> ")"
<expr_list> ::= "" | <expr_list> <expr>.
<program> ::= <expr_list>
```

You can optionally replace the last line with

```
<program> ::= <expr>
```

which means there must always be an enclosing pair of parentheses. (So `()()` and the empty string would not be valid programs, for example.) If you do this, you must do it for input and output strings, as well as programs.

As mentioned above, `(` and `)` may be replaced with any two distinct characters.

**Sandbox notes**

I've been obsessed with designing a simple and elegant language with these properties for some time, but I've never come up with one that really satisfied me. It occurred to me that "source code size of the interpreter" *might* work as a proxy for simplicity and elegance, so I thought I'd give this a try. Suggestions for a better winning criterion (making it a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)) would be welcome.

I'd also welcome suggestions for a snappier title.

Comment: What prevents us from trivially decoding balanced parentheses to an existing programming language, evaluating, and then encoding the result back to balanced parentheses? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQZciUBS3cZOXUHdxsbOTp3LJTU5PyUVKGhhpABU5RKkkAikghWMuVzzoDLVh9YbPurZ@6ijKzHa0BCq6lHv1lh1Oxv12v8@qCY@6piB0PCodxdQC1jHo96pj3r7YLYAJSDWPOpahDDqvzrY0sy8dIX8NAXHAB8FkBMUSvIVCoryU0qTU4F0Zm5qsZU61HUK6hpAA@qAduodnv6od4Wm4aO2yYbaj3o3W1qqc6m7VqQml5Zk5ueBjCvJSFVITMovSwUbCjTCR4EoQ8AhBHISyICi1OLSnBIrWLgpEGUGAA "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online")

Comment: Must all strings of balanced parentheses be valid inputs and programs, or can some of them result in errors?

Comment: i feel like requiring the program to have to be covered in parentheses to work sort of adds an unnecessary step. i would like it if that were removed, or if it was an option whether or not it counts as invalid to have `()()` etc.

Comment: @Adám unfortunately nothing really prevents this. I'd realised that a while after posting this. I'm not sure how to resolve that currently, so I probably won't post this challenge unless I figure out a good way.

Comment: @Zgarb I intended it that every balanced string is a valid program. (But one could always just return the empty string if there's an error. This is another thing I don't like but don't have an easy way to fix.)

Comment: what if you had to implement the language in two distinct languages or something? actually now that i think about it, a bunch of golf languages have python eval...

Comment: @DestructibleLemon that's not a bad idea, but the languages would need to be sufficiently different in order for it to work. I wonder how we could specify that?

Comment: it might be a better idea, in fact, to go to the esolangs room, design a language, then make the challenge be implementing that. perhaps as a bonus, you could have spec options (features or syntax or something which is optional or can be from different choices, with the stipulation that the chosen version of the language has to be as functional as the normal version of the languge)

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I really want language design to be the focus of the challenge, though. (By the way I changed the grammar spec according to your suggestion.)

Comment: "*Your program must be Turing complete. That means that for every computable function from balanced strings to balanced strings, there must be a program in your language that computes it*" Does it? Turing completeness implies the ability to compute any computable function, but the ability to compute a subset of computable functions does not in general imply Turing completeness.

Comment: Moreover, Turing completeness doesn't say anything about *representation*. Minsky register machines are TM-complete, and their state could be put into bijection with balanced strings generated by the grammar `<n> ::= "(" ")" | "(" <n> ")"` `<state> ::= <n> | <state> <n>` giving a Turing-complete system which only computes computable functions from restricted balanced strings to restricted balanced strings.

Comment: "*Your interpreter must correctly implement these semantics. If someone finds a bug in your interpreter, your answer becomes invalid until it's fixed. Be careful of integer overflow!*" is just asking the impossible. No physical implementation can have access to unbounded memory, so strictly speaking no physical implementation can be Turing complete.

Comment: @PeterTaylor your second comment answers the question in your first comment. Do you think I should change anything or is it fine how it is? For your third comment I meant given infinite resources of course - I've amended the text.

Comment: I think my second comment answers the question in my first comment in the negative, meaning that this question would incorrectly disqualify an implementation along the lines sketched in the second comment. BTW I'm pretty sure there are existing languages meeting some of these criteria, if not all, with single combinators. And if there aren't, it's a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hmm, then I'm not sure what your two comments are getting at. Turing machines are Turing-complete with respect to arbitrary strings of tokens; Minsky machines are Turing-complete with respect to integers; the Lambda calculus is Turing-complete with respect to the Church numerals (but not with respect to lambda expressions in general). These things are equivalent because of the bijections you mention. This language must be Turing-complete with respect to balanced strings. What's the problem?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just noticed the word "restricted" in your second comment, which my eyes skipped over when reading it the first time. I do not know what you mean by it. Can you explain?

Comment: If balanced strings are interpreted as ordered forests, the grammar given is essentially a representation of a sequence of integers (the state of the Minsky machine) as an ordered forest in which each node has at most one child.

Comment: I can't think of an objective measure for elegance, that's fairly subjective and considering the issue Adám pointed out, [tag:code-golf] won't do very well. What's your reasons against making it a popcon?

Comment: @BMO good popcon is hard, of course.

Comment: @user202729: I realize that they're difficult to get right, but there are comparable popcons which were received quite well (probably this will be fleshed out even more, so it can only get better). Furthermore this user already has experience in writing good popcons.

Answer (score 1):

## The Euler Masheroni Constant

The Euler Masheroni constant is a very interesting number. It is defined to be
[image]
and appears seemingly everywhere in number theory. Famously, it is unknown whether it is rational, irrational, or transcendental.

## The Challenge:

Pretty simple one here: Given `N`, your program should calculate the Euler Macaroni constant to at least `N` decimal places of prescision. Your score will be the maximum value of `N` for which the program is accurate, and ties will be won by the shortest code.

For refrence, the Euler Macaroni constant to 50 places is

```
0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992
```

Be sure to check out the wikipedia page for more formulas for the Oily Macaroni constant!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: s/Macaroni/Mascheroni/g and s/Oily/Euler/g

Comment: Mmmm. Oily Macaroni. Definitely doesn't stick together that way.

Comment: The easy way to calculate this constant will definitely timeout for very small **n**, and I guess most programs will be infinite anyway.

Comment: You can use MathJax now: $$\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\ln n + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 k\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

#### Find Graph Isomorphism

#### Meta:

I don't know whether there are any known algorithms for solving this problem, that also means I'm not sure whether this is an interesting challenge.
EDIT: Ok it is probably [equally hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization) as the graph isomorphism problem.

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60813/how-to-solve-elastic-band-puzzles)
[graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)[fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)

Given two isomorphic directed (unweighted) graphs with labelled nodes, find an isomorphism between the two graphs.

#### Details

- You have to provide a working implementation of your algorithm.
- You have to provide the complexity expressed in the number of nodes, edges (or possibly other numbers?)
- The graphs can be represented as an adjecency matrix, as set of pairs that represent edges, as an adjecency list or as a native graph type etc.
- The output can be a function that maps the labels of one graph to the labels of the other, as a list as a graph etc.
- If necessary, you can assume that there are no edges with the same start as end node.

#### Examples

to be added...

Comment: (What if it's unknown-complexity? Some heuristics can be quite fast in practice but formally reason about the complexity can be very hard)

Answer (score 1):

## American Checkers AKA English Draughts

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This is a king of the hill challenge for checkers/draughts enthusiasts.

<sub>Note: All code below is written in F#</sub>

### Rules

For this game, I am using the rules from [The American Checker Federation](http://www.usacheckers.com/rulesofcheckers.php) (Note: it tries to download a .doc file). The relevant rules are listed below.

**Moving**

Checkers move forward diagonally one square.
Kings move diagonally one square in any direction.

**Capturing**

*Capturing is required in this variant.*
Checkers jump forward diagonally two squares; they may only jump over an opponent's piece onto a blank square and continue jumping until there are no more pieces to jump, or until they reach the king row.

King jumps follow the same pattern as checkers jumps, but do not have the restriction on moving forward.

**Winning**

The game is won when one player has no more pieces or cannot make any more moves.

**Draws**

A draw is declared when the same position is reached three times or when neither player moves an unkinged checker for 40 moves and there are no captures in those forty moves.

### Play

Each program will take a list of the game history in the form of a `PdnTurn list` ([Read about PDN notation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Draughts_Notation)):

```
type PieceType = Checker | King
type PdnMove = { Move :int list; ResultingFen :string; DisplayString :string; PieceTypeMoved :PieceType Option }
type PdnTurn = { MoveNumber :int; BlackMove :PdnMove; WhiteMove :PdnMove Option }
```

It will return the data in the form of a list of `int`s, where each `int` represents a square on the board. That is, if you have a piece on square 1 and intend to jump to square 10 over a piece on square 6, your program will return `[1; 10]` (notation as an F# list). If any player returns an invalid move, they forfeit the game.

### Scoring

Each player will play three games against each opponent; each win will be scored as 1, each loss as 0, and each draw as 1/2. The loser of the match will be disqualified. At the end of the tournament, the player(s) with the highest score win.

### The Tournament *(incomplete)*:

I set up a website at checkerstreasury.azurewebsites.net. Communication from the server to the player is done with SignalR preferring websockets (you can probably just use websockets without SignalR, but I don't know how). Communication from the player to the server is done with POST requests. I am at work now, but I will post the API and finalize this later.

This challenge feels incomplete; am I missing something?

**Question:** I have my own AI implemented alongside my controller. I intend on submitting this as a base submission, but will not award it the win even if it is the king of the hill. Should I include it in the question, or as an answer? If an answer, should I post it with the question, or wait a while?

Comment: In the interests of the challenge being self-contained I'd suggest providing a summary of the rules that would be sufficient for people to complete it without relying on external resources.

Comment: @Shaggy Relevant rules added.

Comment: I think Mego has an identical koth? Let me check...

Comment: [Here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7484/69850).

Comment: Thanks, @user202729.

Comment: Do you intend to post this at some point? I might be interested to write a challenge and a language-agnostic controller (using STDIO and/or argv for I/O), but apparently you and Mego have both created a sandbox post on the same topic.

Comment: I actually wrote a website for my checkers game over the last few weeks. I'm just working out a few more bugs before it is ready. It has an API for bots to tap in to, and all. Check it out at checkerstreasury.azurewebsites.net (note that steady activity playing the computer by a few users gets it rate-limited as I'm using the free option).

Comment: Website "done". I'll finalize this soon!

Answer (score 1):

## Safely check a password against HIBP v2 range API

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Per https://www.troyhunt.com/ive-just-launched-pwned-passwords-version-2/, what would be the shortest code to safely check a password against the *Have I Been Pwned?* k-anonymity (range) API, as mentioned in the article?

### API overview

Specifically, the API is at:

```
https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/$FIRST_5_CHARS_OF_SHA1
```

and returns a list of SHA1 hashes beginning with the specified 5 chars (more precisely: it returns only the substrings of hashes after `$FIRST_5_CHARS_OF_SHA1`).

For example, given a password `P@ssw0rd`, its SHA1 hash is:

```
21BD12DC183F740EE76F27B78EB39C8AD972A757
\---/\---------------------------------/
  |                     |
  `-- first 5 chars     `-- rest of chars
```

and thus for a request like one of below:

```
https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/21BD1
https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/21bd1
```

the API gives a response like below (`...` represents more lines):

```
...
29B59205F57C2608CAE47E8157621FF7645:1
2B766777053A89201D8257221BBC161E279:2
2D10A6654B6D75908AE572559542245CBFA:2
2D6980B9098804E7A83DC5831BFBAF3927F:1
2D8D1B3FAACCA6A3C6A91617B2FA32E2F57:1
2DC183F740EE76F27B78EB39C8AD972A757:47205
2DE4C0087846D223DBBCCF071614590F300:2
2DEA2B1D02714099E4B7A874B4364D518F6:1
2E90B7B3C5C1181D16C48E273D9AC7F3C16:1
2EAE5EA981BFAF29A8869A40BDDADF3879B:1
2F1AC09E3846595E436BBDDDD2189358AF9:1
...
```

Existence of `2DC183F740EE76F27B78EB39C8AD972A757` in the response means that `P@ssw0rd` was found in some breach and should be considered unsafe. Number `47205` signifies how many times such a password occurs in all the contributing breaches.

### Rules details

- The password must be read from user's keyboard. Per the next rule, it should not be displayed on screen, thus if read from standard input, usually the "character echo" would need to be disabled (e.g. `read -s` in bash). If implemented as a GUI app, e.g. a standard "password input" widget may be used, which would replace typed characters with asterisks or black dots.
- "Safely" means that the solution should not leak raw password to other users of a machine (e.g. the raw password should never appear as part of command line of any subcommand, and should never appear on screen) or outside the machine (websites, etc.). The full hash should not be shared outside the machine either.

  - Specifically, it must be *clear* (for an experienced user of the language) from the code comprising the solution that the raw password (and the SHA) do not leak (as mentioned above). So, for example, the solution's code cannot be downloaded from a remote repository (not sure if it's already included in [default forbidden loopholes list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/78604)).
- The SHA sum of the checked password should be printed on screen, to make it possible to verify correctness of the solution, e.g. by checking SHA sum for `P@ssw0rd`. Other hashes can be printed too or not, but the one matching the checked password must be easy to see (i.e. always first/last/highlighted/...)
- The solution should also display the number of occurrences of the password "in the wild" as returned by the API (i.e. 47205 for `P@ssw0rd`).
- The solution should print at least a 1 character of prompt before reading the answer, so that user knows console is safely in "no echo" mode.

### Extra tag

To keep with the site's  sport spirit, I'm putting no formal restrictions on language. However, *personally* I'm particularly interested in and curious about  "real-world usable" answers. As such, if your answer has the following **"extra" attributes**:

- can be typed in bash as a [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) (with appropriate preamble like `perl -ne` if needed)
- is composed only of printable ASCII characters (no Unicode)

**please** append an extra marker/tag like below in the "title" line of your answer:

> **[bash oneliner: 30 +7]**

where `30` is the length of the actual code in your preferred language, and `+7` is the length of the required preamble/postamble. For pure bash answers, this can be `+0`. Please then also include the actual oneliner, together with the preamble/postamble.

As an explanation, the benefits of a one-liner I'm interested in for "real world users", are such that a one-liner is easy to re-type and execute in console for paranoid users, who would prefer to do it instead of Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V.

---

### Sample naive answer in bash

Split to multiline with `\`s purely for readability:

```
$ (sha=$(IFS= read -s -p "pwned? " pw; tr -d '\n' <<<$pw | shasum ); \
  curl -s https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/${sha:0:5} | \
  (grep -i ${sha:5} || echo "${sha:5}:0") | \
  sed "s/^/${sha:0:5}/")
pwned? 21bd12DC183F740EE76F27B78EB39C8AD972A757:47205
```

One-liner:

```
$ (sha=$(IFS= read -s -p "pwned? " pw; tr -d '\n' <<<$pw | shasum ); curl -s https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/${sha:0:5} | (grep -i ${sha:5} || echo "${sha:5}:0") | sed "s/^/${sha:0:5}/")
pwned? 21bd12DC183F740EE76F27B78EB39C8AD972A757:47205
```

Comment: By the way -- Welcome to PPCG, and thanks for using the sandbox and understanding the site guidelines!

Comment: (to be self-contained, you should also briefly explain what the API does)

Comment: @user202729 Sure, you can; but this loses the usability benefits of it being a [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program#History), such as easy re-typing and easy immediate execution. Arguably  removing the request (and restriction) for "one-liner" is similar in spirit to removing request for "as few characters as possible"/"code-golf". I.e. why even bother with any request...

Comment: Then how do you define one-liner? Doesn't have any 0x0A char? Doesn't have any 0x0D char? Doesn't have any char in that code-page that is used for line feed? What if a programming language uses a code page without any line-feed character? What if a language uses a code page where the newline can be replaced by other character?

Comment: I tried to modify the question to mention "bash one-liner" only as an "extra", non-required attribute, but asking for it to be clearly labeled. I also removed most of my previous comments to de-noise the conversation.

Comment: Why restrict the input to stdin or tty? Any special reasons here that do not accept a GUI version answer?

Comment: @tsh Good question and good idea. My intention was to focus on requiring "no echo", but now I look at it I see I didn't convey that well. I'll try to edit this, though I feel it may be tricky. And also add your idea about GUI, absolutely an oversight on my side. Hm, if you'd have some ideas how to better express this, I'm absolutely interested!

Comment: @tsh Uh, and I forgot to say the most important thing: Thanks! :)

Comment: ... would reading from a file that other users don't have access considered safe?

Comment: @user202729 "The password should be read from user's keyboard" is important for me, so reading from a file is not allowed. Should I change the "should" to "must" to make it clear?

Comment: Looks good. As it's observable whether the SHA/raw password leak (just check what the computer sent to the internet and see if the password is there), the "specifically..." part doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Image to HTML ASCII-Art

---

Given an input image `n`, output each pixel as a `0` using HTML for coloring and `<br/>` as a delimiter for the rows.

---

## Example:

**Input Image:**

[image: Input Image 1]

**Example HTML Output:** https://pastebin.com/jDHZwb4P

**Rendered Output:**

[image: Output rendered as HTML...]

---

## Rules:

- You may color the 0's using any HTML trick you know of (CSS Style, JavaScript, etc)...
- You may use any character other than 0 that shows visible color if you so wish.
- Colors must be exact down to the RGB of the pixel, alpha can be assumed non-existent.
- If you get a malformed image, or an image with transparency, you may error.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: I think you should specify the image format and IO much more. For example PPM would be much easier compared to PNG (example image) or other image formats. Does the full [insert format here]-specification need to be supported? What kind of input (eg. string/bytestring, filename, url,...)? What about the output, does it need to be valid HTML or does successfully rendering with ABC-browser (version XYZ) count?

Comment: @bmo good ideas on all fronts. Im on mobile but Ill make updates. I was expecting a this is a dupe comment though tbh.

Comment: Wanted to leave it open as much as possible. Just anything that can be rendered by a browser as colored text from an image, but Isee no reason to disallow personal browser specifications. Like i could see some dumb IE5 trick to render text being neat as long as they explain it.

Comment: Can we use a space instead of `0`?

Comment: @user202729 Of course! Wait... no, good point.

Comment: Why should we assume alpha is nonexistent when the `opacity` property exists?

Comment: @RamenChef For simplicity sake.

Answer (score 1):

## Find most isolated point

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph)

Given a finite set `S` of points in `d` dimensions, find the *most isolated points*, that is the point with the greatest distance to its closest neighbours.

Or more mathematically, the point `p ∈ S` that maximizes `min {d(p,q) | q ∈ S, q ≠ p}`.

#### Details

- You can return the coordinates of the actual point, or you can alternatively return the index of the point in the input list.
- The *most isolated point* as defined above is not necessarily unique. But you can assume that the given input results in an unique such point.

#### Examples

**1D:**

- `[0,1] (invalid, no unique result)`
- `[0,1,3] -> 3`,

**2D:**

- `[(0,0),(0,1),(1,2)] -> [(1,2)]`

more to be added...

This challenge was inspired by [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89411/how-to-efficiently-compute-the-most-isolated-point). If you find a particularly time-efficient solution please post it there!

Answer (score 1):

### The Challenge

The goal is to write a complete program that prints out every possible tetris block made up of #.

The blocks must have an equal chance of printing in any order and must appear exactly once each. The blocks may have any rotation, rotation may be consistent between executions. No two blocks can be touching. All blocks must have settled on the "floor".

```
ValidExample.exe
                    #   #
## ###      ##   ## #   #
##  #  ####  ## ##  ## ##

TouchingExample.exe
      #
      #  # ##
## ####  #  # ##   ## 
##  # # ##  #  ## ##   

FloatingExample.exe
       #   #             
## ### ## ## #     # ####
##  #   # #  ### ###
```

Use the language of your choice, lowest number of bytes wins

### Questions

- Is the wording clear enough?
- Does the challenge meet the expectations for a challenge here?
- What can I do to remove any ambiguity if there is any?
- Is the formatting for the question / examples ok?
- Would the challenge be "better" if the blocks had to be made up of their corresponding letter (IOJLZST)

Comment: This could be a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/polyomino-generator

Comment: @someone is the new wording better? Replaced random order with a requirement that each order have equal odds.

Comment: I think it is. I don't think the blocks-made-of-letters is a good idea.

Comment: @Sok No input, random order, only tetrominos, no floating restriction. Those seem to be the main differences. Are they enough to distinguish it?

Answer (score 1):

## Find the Intersection [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

#### Challenge

Given some planes in an n-dimensional space, return the intersection of these planes with the highest degree, if it exists.

#### Details

You will be given two integers, n and k, such that 0 < k ≤ n and 1 < n. You will also be given (n-k) hyperplanes within the space **R**<sup>n</sup>. (A hyperplane in the space **R**<sup>n</sup> has (n-1) dimensions.) Your task is to find the intersection between them that has the highest number of dimensions, if it exists. This intersection will have at least k dimensions; it may have more than k dimensions if the inputs are not independent.

For example, if we are working in the 3-dimensional space (**R**<sup>3</sup>), you would be given planes with 2 dimensions. If you are given 3 distinct planes, you would at best be able to find a single point where they all intersect (0 dimensions). If you are given 2 distinct planes, you could find a line where they intersect (1 dimension). Et cetera.

#### Input format

You may choose any standard format to represent hyperplanes in **R**<sup>n</sup>. Here are two formats that I suggest:

1. v<sub>n</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> + ... + c<sub>n-1</sub>v<sub>n-1</sub> + c<sub>n</sub>, where v represents a variable and c represents a scalar constant.
2. c<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> + ... + c<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub> + c<sub>n+1</sub>=0.

For example, consider the plane z=2x-3y in **R**<sup>3</sup>. In format 1, I would write this as v<sub>3</sub>=2v<sub>1</sub>-3v<sub>2</sub>+0, so my program would take in the tuple of scalar constants (2, -3, 0). In format 2, I would rewrite this as 2x-3y-z+0=0, and similarly take the tuple (2, -3, -1, 0). You can choose one of these two formats or another standard format, so long as you provide details in your answer.

You may take in n and k explicitly if you wish, though you should be able to determine both from the list of planes (k is the number of planes, n is one more than the number of dimensions in a plane).

#### Output format

You should output a single plane in the same format as your input. If no intersecting plane exists, you should return something recognizably distinct from other valid outputs of your program (such as an empty tuple, false, a thrown exception, etc.).

#### Test Cases

These use suggested input format 1, with n and k provided implicitly.

> [(c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ..., c<sub>n</sub>), (...), ...] => (c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ...)
>
> In **R**<sup>3</sup>, the intersection of z=-3x-2y, z=5+2x+3y, and z=-x-y-1 is the point (2, -3, 0)
>
> [(2, 3, 5), (-3, -2, 0),  (-1, -1, -1)] => (2, -3, 0) // This doesn't work
>
> In **R**<sup>3</sup>, the intersection of z=4x+y and z=x+2y+1 is the line y=3x-1
>
> [(4, 1, 0), (1, 2, 1)] => (3, -1)

#### Scoring criteria

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

---

## Meta

Can you follow the goal of the challenge and the details I've provided? I've tried to be as clear as possible, but I think I may have been too verbose.

I think my output format needs to change - there's no way to represent a point in **R**<sup>n</sup> the way I've phrased it...any suggestions?

More test cases coming soon.

Comment: The specified input formats force the hyperplane to pass through the origin, but nothing else in the question indicates that restriction.

Comment: Good point. I will fix that, thank you

Comment: "*this can be higher if some of the inputs are equal*" should really be "*this can be higher if some of the inputs are not independent*": three planes can pass through a line without any of them being equal. Other than that, I think you just need the test cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is the feedback I was looking for. I knew there were some holes in my math :)

Answer (score 1):

## Hyperprogramming: X×Y, X^Y, X^^Y all in two

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout), just like the original.

*Heavily inspired by [Hyperprogramming: N+N, N×N, N^N all in one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92944/hyperprogramming-nn-n%C3%97n-nn-all-in-one).*

Your task is to write two programs so that they compute different hyperoperations when they are placed in relation to each other in the form of the mathematical notation for that hyperoperation.

**Full rules:**

Write two rectangular programs of the same size — call them "program A" and "program B" — that each take a single positive integer as input and output that integer. In this case, "rectangular" means that every line is the same length, and that there is no trailing newline. Thus, your two programs will each be composed of M lines of N bytes each.

The catch is that when the two programs are placed next to each other in various positions, they will act as a single program that takes *two* positive integers, X and Y, as input and outputs either X×Y, X^Y, or X^^Y (tetration), depending on the position. Moreover, when the locations of the two programs are reversed, the resulting program will print Y×X, Y^X, or Y^^X — e.g., with X and Y reversed.

The precise location of the two programs with respect to each other is determined by the notation for that particular operation. For instance, if your program A reads

```
*this* is
program A
```

and your program B reads

```
*this* is
program B
```

your program to output X×Y must contain both program's source codes placed horizontally adjacent without any filler inserted, like so:

```
*this* is*this* is
program Aprogram B
```

Because multiplication is commutative, both [AB] and [BA] must function identically.

Your programs to output X^Y and Y^X must contain the code of programs A and B in the locations [ᴀᴮ] and [ʙᴬ], with spaces padding the "exponent" program to the correct horizontal position and optional trailing spaces after each line of the "base" program to pad the layout into a rectangle — no partial padding allowed, it's all or nothing. Padding must be consistent for both X^Y and Y^X (as well as X^^Y and Y^^X later). Illustrated without trailing spaces:

```
         *this* is
         program B
*this* is
program A
```

and

```
         *this* is
         program A
*this* is
program B
```

Finally, your programs to output X^^Y and Y^^X must contain the code of programs A and B in the locations [ᴮᴀ] and [ᴬʙ], with spaces padding the "base" program, and trailing spaces after each line of the "superexponent" program to pad the layout into a rectangle if and only if your X^Y and Y^X programs included trailing spaces as padding. Illustrated without trailing spaces:

```
*this* is
program B
         *this* is
         program A
```

and

```
*this* is
program A
         *this* is
         program B
```

You do not have to support arbitrarily large integers, but your answer should work for a reasonable range of X and Y — that is, it should probably at the very least support all combinations of X and Y up to 3 except maybe 3^^3 = 7625597484987.

Source code reading is allowed, as it would be very difficult to otherwise distinguish X^Y and X^^Y in many languages.

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins.

Note: your score is the total byte count of a single one of your original two programs, not any of the hyperoperation-computing ones — for example, if your programs A and B are each 5×5, your score will be 5×5 + 4 newlines = 29. Since both programs A and B will have identical byte counts, it doesn't matter which one you pick.

Is there anything unclear about this? If so, how could I fix it?

Comment: You may want how exacly do you define "newline". See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160034/shape-identifying-program#comment390106_160125).

Answer (score 1):

> ### Sandbox Notes
>
> - Which tags should go?
> - Is this uncomputable?
> - Should I add more test cases?

## Solve logical statements about arithmetic

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [logic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)
[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sup>Ok, some of these need to go.</sup>

Your task is to determine the truth or falsehood of boolean statements about integer expressions.

**Integer Expressions:**

- `1` is an integer expression.
- If `a` is an integer expression, then `(-a)` is an integer expression representing its negative.
- If `a` and `b` are integer expressions, then `(a+b)` and `(a*b)` are integer expressions representing their sum and product, respectively.
- A string of lowercase Latin letters is an integer expression if it is in scope. A value in scope in an integer or boolean expression is always in scope in all of its subexpressions.

**Boolean Expressions:**

- If `a` and `b` are integer expressions, then `(a>b)` is a boolean expression representing whether `a` is greater than `b`.
- If `a` and `b` are boolean expressions, then `(a&b)` is a boolean expression representing whether they are both true.
- If `a` is a boolean expression, then `(!a)` is a boolean expression testing whether `a` is false.
- If `v` is some string of lowercase letters, and `e` would be a boolean expression if `v` was in scope, then `(v^e)` is a boolean expression that represents whether `e` is true for any integer value of `v`.

### Task

You will be given a boolean expression in any reasonable format (such as a string or a parse tree). You should output one of two distinct outputs depending on whether this boolean expression can be shown to be true or false.

### Test Cases

```
(x^(!(y^(x>y)))) => True
```

Read: for all *x*, it is not the case that any *y* is less than *x*.
In other words, there is no number greater than all other numbers.

```
(!(x^(!(y^((y*y)>x))))) => True
```

Read: there is a number *x* which is less than the square of any *y*.
In other words: there is a number smaller than all squares (any negative number).

```
(x^(x>5)) => False
```

Read: all numbers are greater than 5.

```
(!(x^(!(x>x)))) => False
```

Read: it is not the case that all numbers are not greater than themselves.
In other words: there is a number greater than itself.

```
(y^(x^(!((!(y>(2*x)))&(!((2*x)>y)))))) => False
```

Read: for every two integers *x* and *y*, *y* is neither greater than nor less than 2*x*.
In other words: there is no number divisible by 2.

```
(x^((x*x)>x)) => False
```

Read: all numbers are less than their squares.

```
(x^(!(x>(x*x)))) => True
```

Read: there is no integer greater than its square.

Comment: why not have - as the inverter for integers?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon That was originally because I planned to add subtraction, but then decided to keep it minimal. I'm going to change that. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: What about `!y^(x^!(x>y&x^(a^(b^(x<a*b+1&x>a*b+-1))))&(a^(b^(x+2<a*b+1&x+2>a*b+-1))))))`? (Hopefully I got that right.) Read as "for all y there exists x greater than y, such that x is prime and x+2 is prime."

Comment: In short, yes, it is uncomputable I'm afraid. There's a lot of potential for interesting challenges based on this idea though! One way would be to specify a set of axioms and have it determine whether the statement is provable from those axioms, allowing the possibility that it fails to halt if it isn't. That might be quite complicated for a code-golf challenge though.

Comment: @Nathaniel I somehow failed to realize that you can do prime checking *facepalm*

Comment: @Nathaniel Do you think it's uncomputable if you remove logical negation?

Comment: Do you mean logical negation (`!`) or integer negation (`-`)? (Either way it's not obvious whether it stays uncomputable, I'll have to think about it.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Logical.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I thought about it for a while and it still wasn't obvious, so I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719838/statements-of-arithmetic-without-logical-negation-or-universal-quantifiers)

Comment: @Nathaniel The question you posted isn't exactly the same; my axioms are slightly restricted. There are only integers (and therefore there is no division), and without negation there's no way to simulate logical OR or a "there exists" qualifier. If you allow the "there exists" qualifier your Twin Prime example should be fairly easy to rewrite.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'd for some reason transposed existential (there exists) and universal (for all) quantifiers in my question --- and your point about and vs or is relevant too. I'll reformulate it and repost.

Comment: I've fixed the math.SE question and undeleted it.

Comment: [Exactly same model](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152472/write-it-into-number-theory-style)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit the math.SE question got an answer that looks correct - even without logical negation it's still undecidable, because it contains a known undecidable problem about whether a polynomial has integer roots.

Comment: Info: l4m2 attempted to make this computable by using program halt status the output (which is in turn uncomputable) in a [separate sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16357#16357).

Comment: Try Robinson Arithmetic

Comment: @Akangka It looks like Robinson Arithmetic is also uncomputable.

Comment: @Esolanging Fruit I'm sorry, I meant Presburger Arithmetic. However, it meant that there is no multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

### Title: Lossless Compression

Implement the following lossless compression pseudo-algorithm and its decompressor; scored by the number of **bytes** output by your compression algorithm, after you've put your source-code for both the compressor and decompressor through your own implementation of the compressor algorithm, described below:

### Algorithm Description

Essentially, this is a simple dictionary compression algorithm (which isn't always guaranteed to compress the output, especially for short inputs). You want to scan for sequences of characters that appear multiple times, and then create a lookup; in order to shorten the input string.

The input string to generate your score must contain all characters in your submission;  however the program must also be capable of compressing successfully the test-cases below.

The dictionary (which forms part of the output string) can use any other character as an indexer character, except a single separate character of your choice (`|` in my examples), which is reserved.

The output format should be a sequence of `IndexcharValuestring|` (i.e. `index character`, followed by the `value string`, followed by the `separator` - collectively "the dictionary"); followed by the compressed input string.

### Some examples:

1. `testRattesttestRattesttesttesttestRattest` -> `_test|+Rat|_+__+____+_` - because `test` is represented by `_` and `Rat` is represented by `+`; then the compressed string is shown. each section is separated by the character `|`.

To decompress, simply replace `_` with `test` and `+` with `Rat` in the output (after the last `|`).

The dictionary entry can also be nested - for example:

`ininputinputininput` -> `&in|*&put|&**&*` because `in` is represented by `&` and `&put` is represented by `*`

Exactly which characters end up being grouped will depend on your compression algorithm. For example, the previous string could also be output as `&input|in&&in&`, or `&in|*put&|&&**&put`

Note that the recursive compression could go even further, but at this point the output gets longer again:

`ininputinputininput` -> `&in|*&put|^&*|^*^`

It's up to you how much compression your algorithm performs, as long as it matches or beats the longest of the outputs for each example in this post.

2. `AbcAbcDefDefDeggggggggggggggggggAbc`

could output:

`-Abc|£De|#£f|*ggg|--##£****-`

3. `Well I've heard there was a secret chord That David played and it pleased the Lord But you don't really care for music, do you? Well it goes like this, The fourth, the fifth, the minor fall and the major lift! The baffled king composing Hallelujah. Hallelujah Hallelujah Hallelujah Hallelujah`

could output:

`+ you|/ing |-ed |%pl|¬it|#or|^th|)ll|(he|"T( |$t( |*We) |_Ha)elujah|*I've (ard t(re was a secret ch#d That David %ay-and ¬ %eas-$L#d But+ don't rea)y care f# music, do+? *¬ goes like ^is, "four^, $fif^, $min# fa) and $maj# lift! "baffl-k/compos/_.____`

4. `%Testttttttttt%%%%%%%%`

could output:

`$%%%%|_ttttt|%Tes__$$`

5. `aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789 ?!.,;`

must output:

`aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789 ?!.,;`

(because no compression is possible)

### Acceptance Criteria

In order to class as valid, the algorithm you create should:

- Meet the algorithm description above
- Be able to match or beat the length of the test cases above (shorter = better)
- Output from the compressor (and therefore input for the decompressor) should be in the format shown (dictionary and separator characters may differ). Input for the compressor (and therefore output for the decompressor) should also be in the format shown.

### Sandbox Notes and Questions

- Is the challenge clear?
- Is the scoring mechanism fair? I'm still not sure how to deal with characters vs bytes
- Is the spirit of the challenge clear? (i.e. to actually make an algorithm, rather than simply beat the examples and get the best score)
- Is there any interest in this challenge?

Comment: I'm confused: not only does the output format explanation use `=` but the question explicitly says that `=` is reserved, and yet none of the examples use it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I changed my mind half way through, sorry fixed now

Comment: Mostly irrelevant nitpick: no lossless compression algorithm is guaranteed to make its input smaller, a result often known as the "no free lunch theorem."

Comment: @Nathaniel Good to know, thanks

Comment: How would you score a submission containing characters different from the ones allowed in input?

Comment: @Leo yes, it does limit the source somewhat, doesn't it? What would be better then? - increasing the range of characters allowed to allow any character except, say, `|` (and the dictionary has to key on missing characters only); or keep the limited input and also limit people's source?

Comment: One possibility would be letting people choose the separator character (instead of fixing it as `|`), and requiring that a submission works on inputs consisting of all the required characters plus all the characters contained in the submitted source. This should give enough freedom to make solutions possible in more languages.

Comment: @Leo helpful, thanks. Updated - hope it's clear

Comment: Are you sure that you want to work on characters and not bytes (and thus facing multiple complicated codepage issues)? Especially consider that the program itself is compressed.

Comment: @user202729 could you expand on what issues would occur? I'm not quite sure I get what the issues could be here

Comment: The "program" is most likely an arbitrary byte string, and thus it may be invalid UTF-8.

Comment: @user202729 but it will be convertible to something, using a custom code-page of some sort. Even if it's UTF-16 or some other encoding, right?

Comment: I still feel that it's open to abuse. We had reasons to score by byte count instead of character count.

Comment: @user202729 The scoring is a byte count; just the program uses characters to compress/decompress. The compression ratio for someone using a golfing language is likely to be very poor, compared with say someone using `><>` or even `VB.NET` - but it's the job of the coder to decide which language will get them the best score for the question; right?

Comment: Brute force is the best

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I find it (compress by character, score by byte) unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @user202729 would you compress by byte also then?

Answer (score 1):

## Antigerrymandering

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [map](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) [set-partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-partitions)

From [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149516/73884):

> The United States has a unique love of gerrymandering––the deliberate manipulation of an electoral district to predict certain voting results. Just recently there was a [gerrymandering case](https://www.politico.com/story/2017/10/03/supreme-court-gerrymandering-wisconsin-arguments-243401) brought before the Supreme Court. Gerrymandering, especially when related to race, is ruled illegal and results in the requirement to redraw the district lines.

Gerrymandering has recently been getting even more attention in the news due to this year's congressional elections. Wouldn't it be nice if we could all decide on a simple, nonpartisan way to determine congressional districts?

Your task is to fix settle this discussion once and for all with a determinate program to partition a map into districts.

### What you gotta do

Write a program or function that takes a positive integer `n` and a map (described below) and partitions the map into `n` contiguous districts of equal population (as nearly as possible) while minimizing the total length of the districts' borders.

#### The map

The map is a two-dimensional, rectangular matrix of one or more integers, each integer representing the population of its cell. This can be in any convenient format—an array of arrays, a stream of numbers, or even a JPEG, if desired! You are allowed to take the dimensions of the map as additional inputs.

#### The borders

Each cell in the map is to be treated as a square of side length 1. Total border length is the sum of the lengths of all edges of cells that are also the edge of a district. Note that this will necessarily include the entire perimeter of the map.

#### The partition

The `n` districts must have the lowest possible maximum difference in population from `total population / n`. In the case of a tie, they must have the lowest possible total border length, ensuring compact districts.

Take the following map:

```
1 5 7 8
7 4 2 5
8 5 3 5
```

It has total population 60. To divide it into two districts, each must have population 30. Additionally, each district must be orthogonally contiguous. Both of the following accomplish just that:

```
1│5 7 8
 └───┐
7 4 2|5
     │
8 5 3│5


1 5│7 8
   │
7 4│2 5
   │
8 5│3 5
```

Of these two partitions, the upper has total border length 14 (perimeter) + 5 (border) = 19, while the lower has length 17. Of these two options (and the other one I can see at the moment, the vertical line down the middle is to be chosen, since its border length is the lowest.

Now consider:

```
2 1 2
```

This again has two possible partitions into two districts, but these are tied in border length. Your program or function can return either partition, but it must return the same one each time.

### Output

Lots of options. A string using one non-numeric character for border and another for no border. An array of numbers, with a surjection to the sixteen possible states of a cell's edges. A JPEG, with borders shaded. A pirate's map: "3 steps south. 2 steps east..." Really, anything that can be mapped to a partition. The output format must be consistent.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) in each language wins!

---

## Sandboxy stuff

Any clarification needed?

I'm making some test cases (based on real states' population distributions!); these'll be added soon.

Anything else worth mentioning?

Thanks!

Comment: While flexible output formats are commendable, I personally wouldn't want to check the validity of a program with output formats as broad as "anything that can be mapped to a partition". Now, checking validity of every answer isn't my *job* or anything, but I would want to have the option not be prohibitive.

Comment: [thematically related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149516/jolly-gerrymandering), although going in the opposite direction

Comment: @KamilDrakari I'll think further on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Giuseppe Yep. Meant to link in the question, but wrong link :)

Comment: Will the "real" test cases be small? I ask because a golfed answer to the question as it stands is likely to be geologically slow.

Answer (score 1):

## Get Rid of GoTo's

My (pseudo) code is full of **goto's**! What a mess... Let's change it into a more iterative code.

### SPECIFICATION

Each input consists of:

```
<HEADER> { 
  0: <code> 
  1: <code> (optional) 
  2: <code> (optional) 
  ... 
  99: <code> (optional) 
}
```

where:

**<*HEADER*>**: It is the method signature, but it can be anything. Just repeat it in the output.

**<*code*>**: It is the main code that contains the unwanted goto's and need to be refactored. It is always numbered, starting at 0 and increasing sequentially. **code** can be one of:

- *if* [condition] goto [number] [trailing]: this is where the **goto's** are. The if clause contains any text as a **condition**, that should be repeated in the output. The **number** should be between 0 and 99, and should point to a valid line in the input. The trailing could be a semicolon, a text comment or even nothing at all, but it will **not** appear in the output.
- *return*: the return clause is special because it ends the method execution. In the input code, a return could be followed by others lines reachable by a goto. But in the output code, a return is never followed by a code line. The return can be followed by a semicolon or nothing at all.
- *anything*: anything else is just code clauses that should be repeated somewhere in the output code.

### EXAMPLES

BEFORE:

```
method1() {
    0: printMessage("This is the firstMethod");
    1: if (inputString(0)) goto 3;
    2: return;
    3: setVar(10);
    4: printMessage("Var is set to 10");
}
```

AFTER:

```
method1() {
    0: printMessage("This is the firstMethod");
    1: if (inputString(0)) {
    2:  setVar(10);
    3:  printMessage("Var is set to 10");
    4: } else {
    5:  return;
    6: }
}
```

This is the simplest example. The goto is changed into an if/else structure. The 'return' clause always ends a block (i.e., the code does not continue after it).

BEFORE:

```
public method2() {
    0: addFlag(char, 1);
    1: play(22, 3468, 4433);
    2: int rndNum = random(3)
    3: if(rndNum == 1) goto 6
    4: if(rndNum == 2) goto 8
    5: if(rndNum == 3) goto 10
    6: addItem(36, 54, 0, 0);
    7: return;
    8: addItem(37, 54, 0, 0);
    9: return;
    10: addItem(38, 54, 0, 0);
    11: return;
}
```

AFTER:

```
public method2() {
    0: addFlag(char, 1);
    1: play(22, 3468, 4433);
    2: int rndNum = random(3)
    3: if(rndNum == 1) {
    4:     addItem(36, 54, 0, 0);
    5:     return;
    6: } else {
    7:     if(rndNum == 2) {
    8:         addItem(37, 54, 0, 0);
    9:         return;
    10:    } else {
    11:        if(rndNum == 3) {
    12:            addItem(38, 54, 0, 0);
    13:            return;
    14:        } else {
    15:            addItem(36, 54, 0, 0);
    16:            return;
    17:        }
    18:    }
    19: }
}
```

This example is trickier. The three gotos end up creating nested if/else clauses. Also, as the transpiler can't know if rndNum(3) returns something from [1-2-3], there is also an ultimate else clause afterwards.

BEFORE:

```
public method3() {
    0: int curChar = whoMenu("Test", "Super");
    1: if (firstChar(currentChar, 1)) goto 5;
    2: printMessage("The sun is hot.");
    3: if (YesNo(1)) goto 17;
    4: return;
    5: addVar(currentChar, 10);
    6: addVar(currentChar, 20);
    7: addVar(currentChar, 30);
    8: addVar(currentChar, 40);
    9: addVar(currentChar, 50);
    10: addVar(currentChar, 60);
    11: addVar(currentChar, 70);
    12: addVar(currentChar, 80);
    13: addVar(currentChar, 90);
    14: addVar(currentChar, 100);
    15: printMessage("You feel good");
    16: if (YesNo(1)) goto 17;
    17: addFlag(currentChar, 82);
}
```

AFTER:

```
public method3() {
    0: int curChar = whoMenu("Test", "Super");
    1: if (firstChar(currentChar, 1)) {
    2:    addVar(currentChar, 10);
    3:    addVar(currentChar, 20);
    4:    addVar(currentChar, 30);
    5:    addVar(currentChar, 40);
    6:    addVar(currentChar, 50);
    7:    addVar(currentChar, 60);
    8:    addVar(currentChar, 70);
    9:    addVar(currentChar, 80);
    10:   addVar(currentChar, 90);
    11:   addVar(currentChar, 100);
    12:   printMessage("You feel good");
    13:   if (YesNo(1)) {
    14:         addFlag(currentChar, 82);
    15:   }
    16: } else {
    17:     printMessage("The sun is hot.");
    18:     if (YesNo(1)) {
    19:         addFlag(currentChar, 82);
    20:     } else {
    21:         return;
    22:     }
    23: }
}
```

This example is not so hard, but note there are two goto's going to the same line. As this line does not create a loop, it is permitted (see rules below).

BEFORE:

```
method4() {
    0: printMessage("This is the firstMethod");
    1: if (inputString(0)) goto 4;
    2: printMessage("End is near.");
    3: return;
    4: setVar(10);
    5: if (inputString(1)) goto 2;
    6: printMessage("Var is set to 10");
}
```

AFTER:

```
method4() {
    0: printMessage("This is the firstMethod");
    1: if (inputString(0)) {
    2:     setVar(10);
    3:     if (inputString(1)) {
    4:         printMessage("End is near.");
    5:         return;
    6:     } else {
    7:         printMessage("Var is set to 10");
    8:     }
    9: } else {
    10:    printMessage("End is near.");
    11:    return;
    12: }
}
```

This example is also tricky, because it contains a goto to a previous line. This does not create a loop, but it also creates a block that is repeated twice in the code.

### CONSIDERATIONS:

1) Goto's are **always** associated with an 'if' clause. Replace the goto with a start block '{' clause.

2) Goto's always create an 'if', but **not** necessarily an 'else'.

3) Some clauses can repeat due to more than one goto's going to the same line (directly or not).

4) **There won't be loops.** Example of invalid code:

```
public methodInvalid() {
    0: if(YesNo(1)) goto 2;
    1: printMessage("this code is invalid.");
    2: if(NoYes(1)) goto 0;
    3: printMessage("still invalid.");
}
```

5) Identation in the output is desirable. Each if/else block must be nested with a tab for each nested level. If you want to replace the tab for 2, 3 or 4 spaces, ok, just state it and make it coherent on your code.

6) As there won't be more goto's, the line numbers are **optional** in the output code. Just don't put them out of order, if you want to keep them.

7) The first line can be ignored (just repeat it in the output) and the last line is always the close statement ('}'). These lines are never numbered.

8) The input will always contains line numbers, starting with 0 and a colon. The next line will be 1 and a colon, and so on. **No more than 99 lines will be present.**

9) There is also at least one space (or tab or opening parenthesis) after the if statement, one space before the goto statement and one space before the number after it. So "1:ifagoto2" is invalid, but "1:if a goto 2" is valid and also valid is "1: if(a) goto 2". Spaces (or tabs) are optional before the line numbers and between the semicolon and the start of the code.

10) You **only** need to worry with (a) 'goto's; (b) line numbers; (c) the 'return' clause; and (d) the end of the code (last line). Everything else is gibberish, you don't need to interpret the code. See a valid input below:

BEFORE:

```
fun with code {
    0: gibberish
    1: if a goto 3
    2: gibberish
    3: gibberish
    4: gibberish
}
```

AFTER:

```
fun with code {
    0: gibberish
    1: if a {
    2:  gibberish
    3:  gibberish
    4: } else {
    5:  gibberish
    6:  gibberish
    7:  gibberish
    8: }
}
```

---

Standard loopholes apply, shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Will line number always start with 0 and increase by 1? Is there any un-conditional goto? Will there be any dead code in the input?

Comment: @tsh Yes, the number always start with 0 and increase by 1. No, goto's are always preceded by if's. Dead code in the input? I think so, there is no restrictions against that.

Comment: Suggested title: Code golf [considered harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful).

Comment: Is `if(a)goto 2` allowed?

Comment: @l4m2 No, because "There is at least ... one space before the goto statement"

Answer (score 1):

## Scoring a Game of Composite Boards [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)

#### The Game

Given a board size *n* which must be a [composite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number), the game is played on *m* boards in parallel which correspond to the *m* factors of *n*, excluding 1 and *n* itself.

E.g. if *n* = 12, we get the following 4 boards, where the same character represents the same field:

```
01     012     0123     012345
23     345     4567     6789AB
45     678     89AB
67     9AB
89
AB
```

Two players, *Zero* and *One*, take turns in writing a `0` or `1` respectively on an empty field, which makes that number appear on all boards at the corresponding field.

On each board their goal is to get more rows or columns filled with just their number than their opponent, resulting in the board being either a win for *Zero*, a win for *One* or a draw if both players fill the same number of rows or columns.

The game is won by the player who wins the majority of boards, or results in a draw if both players win the same number of boards.

#### Example

Let's say we have the game `010111010100` of size 12, which corresponds to the following boards:

```
01
01
11 <- row for player One
01
01
00 <- row for player Zero
no columns for either player -> draw

010
111 <- row for One
010
100
-> One wins this board

0101
1101
0100
 ^^
 one column for each player -> draw

010111
010100
^^^^
two columns for each player -> draw
```

As player *One* wins one board and player *Zero* wins none, player *One* wins the game.

#### The Task

Given a completed game as input, output which player won or whether the game was a draw. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest answer in bytes in each language wins.

#### Input

A one-dimensional array/list/string of two distinct values representing the fields of the boards when read left-to-right and top-to-bottom. You can assume that the input describes a valid game, that is the length will always be a composite number and the two values appear either the same number of times for even board lengths or with a difference of one for odd board lengths.

#### Output

Three distinct constant values which correspond to *player Zero wins*, *player One wins* or *draw*.

#### Test Cases

*Draw:* <sub>(All games of size *2*p* where *p* is prime necessarily result in a draw)</sub>

```
0110
101010
11010010
010101010
11001111000100
```

*Zero wins:*

```
110110000
001001110101
1000110101011001
```

*One wins:*

```
111100001
010111010100
1100111100010010
0111010001001101
```

Answer (score 1):

## Curve Matching

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

Given two lists `a`, `b` of the same length `n` find a third list `x` of indices such that `a(i) = b(x(i))` for all indices `i` and `x(i) <= x(i+1)` for all applicable indices `i` and `x(1) = 1` and `x(n) = n`.

#### Details

- The list `x` is not necessarily unique (for instance when `b` has a run of two or more equal entries).
- In the challenge description we use 1-based indices, but you can also use 0-based indices.
- You can assume that `a` and `b` contain integers, floating point numbers, characters or any other types that have a natural order and have at least 256 distinct values.
- You can assume that such an `x` exists. (You can for instance assume that `a=[1,2,3], b=[1,2,1]` are never passed as an input.)

#### Examples

```
a = b = [1,2,3]
x = [1,2,3]

a = [1,3,3], b = [1,1,3]
x = [1,3,3]

a = [1,1,2,3,4,4], b = [1,2,2,3,3,4]
x = [1,1,2,4,6,6] or [1,1,3,5,6,6] etc

a = [1,1,2,3,2,1,1], b = [1,2,1,2,3,2,1]
x = [1,3,4,5,6,7,7]
```

This challenge was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732895/find-optimal-xt-such-that-lt-rxt-as-close-as-possible) on math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Sandbox notes
>
> - Is there anything that is unclear?

## Double Language Supersets

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

For the purposes of this challenge:

- A *language* is a partial mapping from *programs* (strings of bytes) to *outputs* (streams of bytes). Not every output must be finite or produce any elements before looping indefinitely.
- A language **L** is an *superset* of another language **K** if, for every program of length **n** given meaning in **K**, there is a program of length **n** given meaning in **L** which produces the same output. In other words, all programs in **K** can be translated into **L** without requiring any more bytes.

---

*(cops' part)*

As a cop, you must:

- Find two languages, and provide (or link to) a specification in the form of a detailed description or an implementation. Be prepared to answer any questions should ambiguities arise.
- Define a new "solution" language which is a superset of both of the others. This can be in the form of a detailed document, implementation, or a proof that such a language exists.

You should reveal the first two languages, but keep the solution language secret.

The cop whose submission takes the longest to crack is the winner.

---

*(robbers' part)*

As a robber, you must:

- Find an existing cop submission.
- Define a new language which is a superset of both of the languages provided by the cop. This can be in the form of a detailed description, an implementation, or a proof that such a language exists.

The robber who cracks the most cop submissions is the winner.

Comment: So it's a partial mapping?

Comment: @user202729 Yes

Comment: I don't think that polyglot makes sense here.

Comment: I don't think this really makes sense as a c'n'r. Both cops and robbers are trying to do the same thing, which is to prove that every program which is valid in both languages gives the same output in those languages. The robber doesn't have to outwit the cop by beating a score or working within extra constraints which the cop chooses and can try to use to add false clues. The only real asymmetry is that the cop chooses the languages, and the only way to exploit that to make it interesting is to make one of them a homebrew which is "specified" with an obfuscated implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

The following is an idea I hope to eventually make into a full king of the hill.  I've never written or participated in a king of the hill so help would be appreciated.

Here is how this is going to work.  You are going to be able to write the brain behind a bot.  Your bot will have a limited amount of energy to work with.  It won't have to expend energy to move around normally, however every time it moves while carrying something it will expend 1 unit of energy.  When your bot hits zero energy it won't be able to move any longer and will <s>die</s> have to take a nap.

The goal is to make bots that will take agar from sources to their corresponding goals.  However the sources and goals will be too far apart for a single bot to carry a piece of agar all by themselves so **you will need to work with other bots to achieve your goals**.

### Specifics

#### The course

The course will likely be a square grid of yet determined size.  On the south and east ends will be sources of agar, which will replenish as it is drained by the bots.  On the north and west ends will be goals.  Agar placed in the goal will disappear.  Agar from the east source should be placed in the west goal and agar from the south source in the north goal.

#### The bots

Each player will be given control of 1 bot.  Bots will be implemented as a rather simple state-machine. You will implement your bot as a function that takes inputs and produces outputs.  At each step of the program a the bot will receive the following pieces of information:

- Whether each of the four squares adjacent to it is inside our outside of the arena.
- Whether there is agar in each of the four squares adjacent to it, and the square it is in.
- Whether there is another bot in each of the four squares adjacent to it.
- Whether it is carrying agar currently.
- How much energy it has remaining.
- An additional 2 bit state, to be explained.

From those inputs the bot will produce two outputs:

- An action, which is either a direction to move, picking up agar, or placing agar back on the ground.
- A 2 bit state to be passed on to your bot at the next step.

The 2 bit state acts as your bot's memory.  It's not a lot so you should use it wisely.

#### Movement

Your bot has pretty free movement.  It can move into any empty space.  However there are two limits on movement.

- You may not move outside of the course
- You may not move into a space that has agar if you are carrying agar.

I am not yet sure how I will handle bot collisions.

#### Carrying

Your bots can carry agar.  They can only carry one piece of agar at a time.  To pick up agar a bot must be standing where the agar is located and perform a pick up action.  Placing agar works in much the same way.  If a bot is carrying agar they may perform a place action to put the agar down where they stand.  Placed agar will remain there until a bot picks it up and moves it.  Picking up and placing agar does not cost energy, however moving while holding agar does cost a unit of energy for every movement.

#### Scoring

*Scoring is still up in the air, once I have a working controller I will finalize scoring aspects.  That being said thoughts, questions and suggestions are more than welcome.*

Each piece of agar will remember which bots helped move it and how many steps they took.  Upon being put into the correct goal agar will award every bot 1 point for every step they took while holding the agar.  Agar left on the field or put in an incorrect goal will award no points.

More points is better.

I'm not sure how koth scoring usually works overall so you guys might want to help me with that.

### Controller

Once I have the idea down I will start to write a controller.  I may need some help from people more experienced in koths in getting the basics down.

I intend to write the controller in [elm](http://elm-lang.org/) because I like functional programming and I would like the controller to be runnable from in browser.  Answerers will not have to write in elm they will instead write in a toy language I have yet to write the specifics for.

Comment: A few points, all related to a particular event/strategy: 1) Do bots pick up/put down agar in any adjacent square, or specifically on their current square? 2) If a bot picks up then puts down agar without moving in between, does that use energy? 3) Mostly dependent on 1, but if a bot picks up agar and puts it down somewhere else, does that count for scoring even if the bot itself didn't move in between?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Bots must stand on agar to pick it up, and placed agar will appear where they stand when they place it.

Comment: Since you're passing the state with every function call anyways, you could also run each bot as a single process which would allow people to participate in any language of their choice. I once planned a KOTH (which has some copyright issues and I can't post it) and wrote a Python framework, if you're interested I'd share it. Basically it creates a new process for each bot and controller-bot communication works via pipes, st. the bot can just read *stdin* and write to *stdout*. This would probably attract more participants than forcing a language.

Comment: @BMO The main reason I am using purescript is that it is runnable in browser.  I could definitely make this language agnostic but I would have to make it into a desktop application.  I'd greatly prefer a challenge that can be run in browser.  In addition purescript's pattern matching makes it so you don't really have to know purescript to write a working bot.  I can easily write a form that can be filled out to make a bot.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense that people are able to run it in a browser. I've never used purescript but it seems like a nice language. I'm not sure though if people would be willing to get involved with it (not everyone is comfortable with strong type systems), however it seems like there are a lot of people that know JavaScript. So it's probably a good choice for a KOTH.

Answer (score 1):

> **Unless someone can convince me otherwise I think this is too close to [Are the brackets fully matched?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched) to be an interesting new challenge, so I won't submit it.**

## Well-formed Parentheses Gone Wild

The object is to determine if the "parentheses" in a string are well-formed, in the sense that they are balanced and well-nested.

For example `[(ab(c!{})n)]` is such a string, while `[(ab(c!(d)x){)}]` is not (balanced, but not well-nested due to the last closing `)` appearing before the closing `}`).

### But wait, there's more

Those examples took advantage of the commonly understood meanings of the pairs `()`, `{}`, and `[]`. But any characters could be opening and closing parentheses, and not just the obvious ones.

### Input

The input consists of two strings with optional trailing newlines. The characters can be any ASCII printable character (hex 20 to hex 7E).

The first string has an even number of characters with no duplicates. Each successive pair of characters defines a pair of opening and closing parentheses. The second string is the test string.

### Output

Truthy or falsy value (with optional trailing whitespace) for whether or not the parentheses in the test string are well-formed (balanced and well-nested). If either the first or second strings are empty, the answer is defined to be truthy.

### Some Tests

Format:

```
String1
String2
Output
```

Tests:

```
(){}[]
[(ab(c!{})n)]
truthy

(){}[]
[(ab(c!(d)x){)}]
falsy

()[]<>
[(ab(c!(d)x){)}]
truthy

                      <---- empty parenthesis string
%$w%jS(5gS
truthy

(){}[]
                      <---- empty test string
truthy 

qwertyuiop
q##qCfet^Hy&&r$wuiwgJo7({)}erxp
truthy

@#$%^&
super b$fox$#@%%g ongshow^&
falsy
```

### Scoring and Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest entry wins.
- Standard loopholes forbidden and standard rules apply.

Comment: I believe [this is a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124385/is-there-an-unmatched-parenthesis-in-this-string)

Comment: @NathanMerrill this challenge has the input define its own parentheses and require that it's well-formed. That would definitely need different code.

Comment: Why not go with 2 separate strings in any convenient format? Can the open and close parentheses be the same, e.g. quotes?

Comment: @StephenLeppik - two strings in a convenient format would be better. The `,` and `!` are not relevant to the problem. Would it be canonical to say "two strings with optional trailing newlines"? I want to include the space ` ` as a possible character in either string.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Open and close parentheses must be different, as implied by the even number of characters with no duplicates in the first string.

Comment: Is it possible to take a list of length-2 string (for the first input)?

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched) is a better dupe. The 05AB1E answer and the (20-byte) Pyth answer can be directly ported to this challenge. The Javascript answer... need some join-with-`|` and regex construction.

Comment: I'm thinking https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched is close enough to make this challenge uninteresting. What's the protocol? Do I delete this or just leave it so nobody else tries the same?

Comment: You could always spice up the rules to make your challenge unique.

Comment: What if there was an order on the different parenthesis so that () has to be closed before [] can be open or something along these lines? So your String1 in the example would define an order.

Answer (score 1):

## Knightmare in 1024 bytes of (JavaScript?)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)

---

## Board

The board is a 16x16 grid of squares. It does not wrap, so the outer edges are an impassable boundary.

## Pieces

Each piece is like a Chess knight, and will be referred to as a ***knight***. It moves to a square that is two squares away horizontally and one square vertically, or two squares vertically and one square horizontally.

[image: Chess board showing a knight and its moves]

A knight can move to any of these squares, regardless of whether it is occupied. There is no limit to how many knights may occupy the same square at the same time.

## Players

This is a 2 player game. Each player has 16 knights. Knights cannot be removed from the board so there will still be 16 knights per player at the end of the game.

## Turns

Each turn both players move all 16 of their knights simultaneously (that is, all 32 knights move at the same time).

## Costs

Each square has a ***cost***, which is a non-negative integer, initially set to zero. Each time a knight visits a square, the cost of that square is increased by 1. To be explicit, if N knights land on a square in the same turn, that square's cost is increased by N.

## Penalties

After each turn, each knight incurs a ***penalty***, which is the cost of the square it occupies, plus the number of other knights occupying the same square (regardless of whether they are friend or foe).

The player's ***cumulative penalty*** is zero at the start of a game, and is increased by each knight's penalty each turn (for all 16 of its knights).

## Winning

A game ends after 1024 turns. The winner is the player with the lowest cumulative penalty.

## Input

The player is supplied with:

- an array showing the cost for each square
- an array showing the number of its own knights for each square
- an array showing the number of its opponent's knights for each square
- an array showing the total knights for each square
- an array of coordinates for its own knights
- an array of coordinates for its opponent's knights
- its own cumulative penalty
- its opponent's cumulative penalty
- the turn number

## Output

The player responds with a move for each of its 16 knights. Each move is a number from 0 to 7, indicating the direction to move, numbered clockwise from the top. The response must be received within 5ms.

## Invalid moves

Since the edge of the board is impassable, sometimes there will be fewer than 8 valid moves available for a given knight. If an invalid move is given, it will be reflected vertically and/or horizontally to give a valid move, and that move will be made instead. This means every knight will move every turn - none will ever stand still.

## Code

Each entry provides the body of a JavaScript function that is no more than 1024 bytes.

---

## Sandbox questions

- I'm not settled on which language to use yet. I like the idea of using a different language for each KotH. I'm considering maybe Japt or APL for this one. Ideally something terse since golfing is part of the challenge here.
- Fixed starting configuration (for example, players in a line along opposite edges of the board), or random initial placement?
- Leaning towards a board that does not wrap. Any reasons to avoid this?
- I've put placeholder values for the number of bytes, the size of the board, and the number of knights per player. Any feedback on how to improve these values welcome.
- I'm not sure whether to make staying still a valid move. I'd prefer to keep it simple and have 8 possible moves with no possibility of staying still.
- I'm currently deciding between the penalty being the cost plus the number of other knights on the same square, or the cost times the number of knights on the square.
- I need to settle on input and output that are suitable for both golfing the contestant code and keeping things running reasonably quickly.

Comment: "cost plus number of other knights" means other knights aren't *that* much of a hindrance, since the cost of visiting a square with a knight in it is only one point more than visiting a square that was previously visited. (And I would expect most squares to have been previously visited multiple times.) "cost times number of other knights" makes it very different, as it becomes almost entirely about avoiding other knights, much more than avoiding previously visited squares. I'm not sure which is best, just pointing this out.

Comment: Also: when I read "knightmare", I imagined a child wandering through computer generated rooms wearing a helmet that you can't see out of, guided by Treguard and his sidekick Pickle the Elf. This may be because I am a British person of a certain age.

Comment: Maybe I need something in between then. Will give it some more thought

Comment: I am also a British person of a certain age. I may change the title before posting...

Comment: I feel like there's very little room for strategy here.  Moving to the smallest-cost room will pretty much always be the best strategy, and if it's not, it will only be wrong by a couple of points (and a single-turn look-ahead will greatly mitigate that)  I think that there will be too much randomness (in how the enemy moves) to really make this interesting.

Comment: I don't personally think challenges should impose a maximum byte count. Is there a reason that only allowing 1kB is important?

Comment: I'm against minimum required scores in code golf, agreeing entirely with [Martin's arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8928#8928). In that context the byte count is the score, and I wouldn't want to exclude anyone, or prevent someone from posting a long answer that can gradually be improved over time. I see this KotH as different. The limit is not intended as a barrier to entry. I want to choose a limit that will allow anyone to post a basic entry, and then gradually improve it over time as they find ways to fit more in.

Comment: I want a KotH that has some of the aspects of a code golf challenge. That was the initial idea, and the knights came later. If they are not considered a good fit then I will consider changing the game to something that fits a byte limited challenge better. The other option is to have no byte limit but make the number of bytes somehow penalise the player, whether in increasing their score or restricting their abilities within the game. That seems harder to get right, so I'm going with a byte limit as the simplest way of including short code as a game constraint.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I've also worried about this. This is part of why I'm considering a significantly increased penalty when sharing a square with other knights, to allow blocking off the opponent knights from lower cost regions. I feel like that will be one of the most important things to fine tune carefully before posting the challenge

Comment: Another way of thinking about the byte limit: Code golf has a single fixed task and the byte count varies. This KotH has a single fixed byte count and what people choose to do with it varies.

Comment: Contests like [Tweetable Mathematical Art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art) have a byte limit but are too broad. The idea with this KotH is to have a byte limit combined with an objective way of measuring competitors against each other, making the requirement very specific (outcompete the others) while leaving the method open.

Comment: @trichoplax Your code-golf goals might be better achieved if you make a custom language for this.  If you make a more-or-less "flat" language, and score it by the number of lines, then you have the challenge of "fitting stuff in", without resorting to typical golfing.

Comment: I think the limited byte count is a good idea, or could be, as long as optimal solutions to the challenge are much too complicated to fit into the available space. (See [Paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) for an example where this worked well, in my humble opinion). That might not be the case here though, as the challenge might not require very complicated strategies, and 1024 bytes is pretty huge even for Javascript. (In Starry Night most competitive entries used most of that space for data rather than code.)

Comment: Yes I need to fine tune the number of bytes once I'm settled on the rules and other parameters. I want it to be restrictive enough that people looking at the existing solutions think "I have a better idea than that", but the byte limit forces using different strategies that wouldn't be competitive with unlimited code

Comment: What I don't want is a KotH where you write the same solution you would have without the limit, and then have the extra task of golfing it. I want the limit to lead to innovation, not just extra work

Comment: JS-only? That's a bad enough restriction at the best of times, but when you're also imposing tight time limits it's worse.

Answer (score 1):

## Golf the linux kernel

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

This file *[to do: make the file and provide a link]* contains all the code in the Linux kernel, concatenated together into a single file. Your task is to output this exact file.

The code in the file has been stripped of all comments, except for the copyright notice at the top, which is a legal necessity in order to distribute it.

This is a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge, so your score is the size of your submission in bytes, and the smallest score wins.

If your submission will contain multiple files (for example, code and a separate data file), please take note of the rules on [scoring](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/21034) and [directory structure](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12821/21034) for multi-file submissions. Any data that your code uses must be included in your score.

> **Sandbox note**
>
> This is an unusual [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge, in that the specified output consists of a really huge file. (Probably in the hundreds of Mb.) Normally that would mean built-in compression methods would dominate, but the Linux kernel has a lot of structure in it, both due to the grammar of C and due to the strict coding standards. For that reason I would expect customised algorithms to out-perform standard ones, so it should make for an interesting open-ended challenge along the lines of [Paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) or [Write Moby Dick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately).

Comment: I think you should have to output it; your program is a way of distributing it. IANAL though.

Comment: Because the header is very small in comparison with the text, it should not be too much of a problem.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 IANAL either. I imagined it would only count as distribution if you give it to someone else. But since I'm not sure I've changed it for now.

Comment: @Nathaniel You're giving it to everybody on the internet, so it's distribution.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 right, and that's why I'm including the header. But for someone running their own program and verifying the output, they wouldn't be giving it to anyone, hence no need to reproduce the header. But I've changed it for now anyway.

Comment: @Nathaniel That's true. If somebody submitted it, though... (This is just for others reading this; I'm not arguing with you.)

Comment: @user202729 it shouldn't be a problem by the numbers, but it would result in a challenge that amounts to "compress this huge amount of code (plus this small amount of English text)", which I thought might be annoying. Not really sure though.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 gah, that opens up a whole can of worms I hadn't thought of - the entries to this competition probably count as works derived from the Linux kernel, and hence have to be distributed under the GPL themselves. That probably spells the end for this challenge idea, unless I use some other large body of code that's public domain or released under a much more permissive license.

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh... Well, erm... I don't think they... Wait, they would... Ask on [opensource.se]. They'll know.

Comment: It might be a good idea to change scoring to be more like the Moby Dick and Starry Night challenges, where the scoring is based on "similarity" rather than requiring an exact match. I think that should get around some of the Open source issues since the output wouldn't really contain the kernel or anything runable at all, and imo tends to favor custom implementations over built-in compression due to higher tolerance for lossy approximations.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Then there would be empty submissions... no. Also how will it be different from Moby Dick then?

Comment: @user202729 if I wanted to go in that direction, there is a numerical parameter in the Moby Dick scoring system, which in retrospect was set a bit too high. I could change it to `L+E` or even `0.5L+E`, which would result in a significantly different challenge, and the different regularities in the target text would make a big difference also. But I doubt that would really get around the legal issues, and I prefer the pure-ness of this idea, if I can get it to work. I'll just have to find a project with a different license - I'm sure that exists somewhere.

Comment: Or I could use a completely different similarity measure. I've been thinking about something based on log loss, which would work much better as a similarity metric, at the cost of being more complicated to explain and implement. A follow-up to Moby Dick is in the works at some point, but I'm very aware of the need to make it different enough from the original.

Comment: I've seen claims similar to "*For that reason I would expect customised algorithms to out-perform standard ones*" fail to be backed up by *answers* outperforming standard algorithms enough times that IMO it's not worth posting a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge unless you have written a reference answer which outperforms bzip2 and gzip.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's a fair point --- if I find a body of code with a suitable license I will do that, and I won't post if I'm wrong. (I did a similar test for Moby Dick.)

Answer (score 1):

## Decode my Alphabet Code (Cops)

<sup>*This is my first C&R challenge, so I thought I'd better post it in the sandbox. This is only the Cops thread and it's still missing some usual C&R rules (such as explaining what should be done once a submission has been cracked).*</sup>

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

---

This is the Cops' thread of a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. *[Link to the Robbers' thread goes here.]*

## Your task

As a Cop, you must write either a full program or a function that meets the following requirements.

#### Input

A non-empty string made of at most 26 distinct characters in a given code page. The input is guaranteed to be valid.

The code page is either UTF-8 or -- at your option and if applicable -- a specific code page used by your language.

#### Output

A string of the same length and in the same code page where the first encountered character is replaced with **A**, the second encountered character (distinct from the first one) is replaced with **B**, and so on.

For instance, the expected output for `Hello, World!` is `ABCCDEFGDHCIJ`, where `A=H`, `B=e`, `C=l`, etc.

#### Code restriction

Your code must be a valid input for itself. In other words, it must consist of at most 26 distinct characters in the chosen code page. (But of course, each distinct character may be used several times.)

## Your submission

Your submission must contain:

- The language used
- The code page used
- The size of the code in this code page
- A brief description explaining the nature of your code (program or function) and the I/O formats it's using, in case it slightly differs from string/string.
- The output produced by applying the transformation to your code

Example:

```
# MyLanguage, 32 characters in MyLanguage code page

A function taking an array of characters and returning a string.

ABCADAEFGHIEJKDKLMEBCLNEOPPJLNEO
```

## Robbers' task

Robbers must crack your submission by finding a working program that produces *exactly* the same output once transformed. (Finding a shorter program is *not* a valid crack.)

## Rules

If your answer remains uncracked for a week, you can mark it as *Safe* and unveil the original code.

The winner is the shortest uncracked answer. In the case of a tie, the oldest answer wins.

---

#### *Sandbox questions*

- *Is it a dupe or too close to an existing challenge?*
- *[**In the original version**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16285/3), the encoding was forced to UTF-8. I'm still not sure which option is the best, so I'm interested in any feedback about that.*
- *All other comments and suggestions are much welcomed!*

Comment: Do spaces count too ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Yes, all distinct characters are taken into account. (The space becomes **F** in my _Hello, World!_ example.)

Comment: I suggest only using bytes. Most languages I know of have SBCS anyway, otherwise the translation from UTF8 to bytes are straightforward enough.

Comment: To be clear, this is not [tag:code-golf], correct?

Comment: @user202729 Using only bytes is indeed another possibility. But it may make the submissions quite harder to check. For instance, if you pass the posted UTF-8 representation of a Jelly program to this same Jelly program _which is expecting it in its own code page instead_, it's likely to fail.

Comment: @user202729 I need to add that the shortest uncracked answer wins. So, I suppose it should be tagged as code-golf as well? (Although the primary winning criterion is to remain uncracked.)

Comment: If a language only uses less than 26 characters, can we only support up to that many letters of the alphabet?

Comment: @JoKing No, the program must support all inputs. (But of course it's fine if the code itself is only using a couple of distinct letters.)

Answer (score 1):

### Integers as "polynomials"

Suppose we use successive digits of an non-negative integer for coefficient, base and power respectively and construct a "polynomial". For a 4-digit number we'll have:

`abcd`  -> `a*b^c + b*c^d + c*d^a + d*a^c`.

Each digit must go through the three roles exactly once. For the last two members we wrap around the right edge and use the first/second digit again.

For example 1234 will represent the following "polynomial":

`1*2^3 + 2*3^4 + 3*4^1 + 4*1^2` -> `1*8 + 2*81 + 3*4 +4*1` -> `186`

We started with an integer and ended with an integer. That gives me the idea that we can feed the result into the procedure again and keep calculating. As it seems the numbers will sooner or later start repeating, leading to an endless loop. For example:

`4 -> 1024 -> 12 -> 4 -> ...`

I'm interested in how many cycles are needed until we come to a number that has already been calulated.

### The Task:

Start with a non-negative integer and calculate my "polynomial" from it. Keep calculating using the result as input until you reach a number that has already been calculated.

Your answer must be theoretically correct if your language's integer types had infinite width, but you may use any integer type with at least 8 bits

### Input:

You can take the input as:

- A non-negative integer
- A list of digits
- A string

### Output:

A single integer - the number of cycles until a known number is reached.

### Winning criteria:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes in each language wins. Explanations of the code are welcome!

### Test cases:

```
 0:  1
 1:  1
 2: 34
 3:  5
 4:  3
 5:  3
 6: 29
 7: 48
 8: 33
 9: 20
10:  1
11: 35
12:  3
13: 30
14: 34
15:  2
16:  3
17: 35
18:  4
19:  5
20:  1
21:  3
22:  4
23: 79
24: 78
25: 36
26: 34
27: 15
28: 41
29: 57
30:  1
31: 30
32: 79
33:  3
34: 10
35: 45
36: 32
37:  9
38: 64
39: 10
40:  1
41: 34
42: 78
43: 10
44: 30
45: 16
46: 39
47: 13
48: 96
49:  7
50:  1
51:  2
52: 36
53: 45
54: 16
55: 11
56: 40
57:  4
58: 12
59: 17
60:  1
61:  3
62: 34
63: 32
64: 39
65: 40
66: 30
67:  4
68:  6
69: 77
70:  1
71: 35
72: 15
73:  9
74: 13
75:  4
76:  4
77:  9
78: 38
79:  6
80:  1
81:  4
82: 41
83: 64
84: 96
85: 12
86:  6
87: 38
88: 97
89: 13
90:  1
91:  5
92: 57
93: 10
94:  7
95: 17
96: 77
97:  6
98: 13
99: 69
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[polynomial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomial)

Comment: "*Not surprisingly the numbers will sooner or later start repeating, leading to an endless loop*" Do you have a proof of this? It seems plausible but not obvious that no chain escapes to infinity.

Comment: @Peter Taylor -  No, I don't have any proof. Maybe I need to change the description?

Comment: I've found a proof: 12 x 9<sup>10</sup> = 4.1841412812 x 10<sup>10</sup>, so any number with 12 or more digits maps to a number with fewer digits. There is one thing which I think it's probably worth adding, and that's a statement about overflow. Options include "Your answer must be correct if intermediate values don't exceed N bits, but may be incorrect if they do exceed that"; "Your answer must be theoretically correct if your language's integer types had infinite width, but you may use any integer type with at least 8 bits".

Comment: @ Peter Taylor Thank you for your help! You are completely right abiut the overflow - I have used J's extended precision to make the test cases. I'm going to update the description.

Answer (score 1):

## Relational Division

Given a database of colored marbles in bins, find which bin has the most marbles of a certain color. In database administration, this task is known as *relational division*.

### Example

*Input marbles (flexible format, this is just one possibility):*

```
red,A
blue,B
green,C
red,B
red,A
blue,A
```

*Input color:*

```
red
```

*Program output:*

```
A
```

### Format

Each 'marble' is represented as a `(color, bin)` pair, so the entire database of marbles is represented by a list of these pairs. The list can be fed into your program in any reasonable way so long as the association of the input data remains between colors and bins -- for example via CSV on stdin in `color,bin` pairs split on newlines in string-manipulation programs, or perhaps via a list of `(str, str)` tuples as a parameter to a function in a language like Python. It's up to you.

In my examples, I'm using `string`s to represent colors and bins, but you can use any data type that is capable of representing at least 1000 distinct values in your programming language (i.e. no booleans). Examples of other acceptable data types would be integers or floats so long as you're consistent.

It's very important that colors cannot be used as bins, and bins cannot be used as colors (i.e. the set of bin identifiers and the set of color identifiers must be disjoint). If this isn't true, the result is undefined.

In addition to the marble database, your program takes in a color identifier, again in whatever way is most convenient to do I/O of a single value in your language. Your program **must** output or return a unique identifier for the bin that contains the most marbles of that color.

The result is undefined if the input color doesn't exist, or if there is a tie between multiple bins (i.e. if the input color is `red`, there are 70 red marbles in total, and two bins both have 30 red marbles). Your program should be expected to handle up to 1000 input marbles without much difficulty.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest program wins, with submission time (earlier is better) as the tiebreaker.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: If it's a function, it must output to stdout too? Huh?

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, bug fixed!

Answer (score 1):

## Nice Tile Connector

Your task is to connect the tiles given to you in the input by removing the lines on sides they connect

### Input

A set of tiles that are not yet connected

### Output

The tiles with the walls removed in the right places to connect them

### Method

Each tile in the input looks like this:

```
___
|~|
|_|
```

Every air space looks like this:

```
...
...
...
```

On a tile, the top line is in front of the side lines, which are both in front of the bottom line. That means the top line will always replace the `|` characters that would be there on the sides, and the side lines will always replace the `_` characters that would be there on the bottom.

Each tile must have any lines removed that are adjacent to other tiles

### Example

The input

```
...______...
...|~||~|...
...|_||_|...
...___...___
...|~|...|~|
...|_|...|_|
...______...
...|~||~|...
...|_||_|...
```

The output

```
...______...
...|~~~~|...
...|~~__|...
...|~|...___
...|~|...|~|
...|~|...|_|
...|~~___...
...|~~~~|...
...|~~~~|...
```

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), smallest solution in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Conway's Battlegrounds

[game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

---

- [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83988/72792)

Conway's Battlegrounds will be a mix of [PUBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown's_Battlegrounds) and [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). In this challenge, you will need to make a Python bot that will play it.

### Game rules

The controller, at the beginning of the round, will create a two-dimensional 500x500 toroidal (edge wrapping) board with [chosen cells being alive](https://github.com/Soaku/KoTH-CBG/blob/master/board.md), the others are dead.

The players are then separated into equal teams, each with 4 bots. If there isn't enough players in the team, some of them might be duplicated.

### Gameplay

#### "Parachuting" phase

Everybody in the game will be given the array representing the starting state of the board. Each bot's class will be initialized, with these arguments in order:

- `num` - an int between 2 and 5 inclusive, representing the number you'd be marked with on the map during the game. The other numbers in the range will be your party members.
- `area` - Dictionary, where each key is a 2 value tuple `(x,y)` and each value is either a 0 (dead cell) or 1 (alive cell)

During this phase, each bot's method `parachute` will be called exactly 10 times. It will be given only one argument:

- `team` - 4 item dictionary with your and each teammate's ID (between 2 and 5) as key and a 2 item tuple as value, representing the `(x,y)` position they chosen, or `None` if they didn't yet chose any.

The method can return a 2 value tuple, representing where the bot want to start or None, if the bot can't decide. The returned value will be visible to every other teammate.

The method will be called again, even if the player already chose a location. The next return value will replace previous. You can prevent that by returning `team[self.num]`, assuming you saved the `num` parameter from `__init__`.

*It is recommended to spawn your bot near teammates, so it's easier to cooperate later.*

If the method has been called the 10th time and the bot didn't return that time a `(int, int)` tuple, it will be removed from the game.

Each bot will then be spawned at a random location in a 9x9 rectangle, with the returned location in the center. The bot will not collide with other players.

### Starting phase

This phase will take exactly 25 turns. It's almost the same as the later, main phase of the game, except that no cell will die or be created in it.

The `start` method of each bot will be called once every turn. It will take these arguments in order:

- `area` - Basically the same as in the previous phase, but with several modifications:

  - It will be only a 25x25 fragment of the map, with the bot in the middle.
  - It might also contain the ints in range 2..5 representing each teammate.
  - It might also contain the int `-1` representing an opponent.
- `turn` - The number of the turn, starting with 0. In the last turn of the phase it will be 24.
- `chat` - a list of new chat messages, stored in tuples `(author_id, msg_id)`

The method must return a 0..4 value tuple or list, which may contain up to three actions the bot will perform during it and optionally a single chat message. Each item in tuple is a one move, depending on the value:

- Falsy values (0, `None`, `False`) - Do nothing
- Positive int - Move in given direction, according to the rule (where the bot is in the center):

  ```
  1 2 3
  4   6
  7 8 9
  ```

  Bot can only move to a neutral position.
- Negative int - Replace a neighbour dead cell with a neutral alive cell, according to the rule above, ex. `-1`.
- String -  Send a chat message with the given ID, explained later

### Main phase

Similar to the previous phase, but in this one, cells can die. It won't end until only one team is on the board.

The `main` method of each bot will be called once every turn. It will take these arguments in order:

- `area` - Same as in starting phase
- `team` - Dictionary with position of teammates `id: (x, y)`
- `turn` - The number of the turn, starting with 0. In the last turn of the phase it will be 24.
- `hp` - The amount of health points the bot has, explained later. Initially 4.
- `chat` - a list of new chat messages, stored in tuples `(author_id, msg_id)`

The return value is the same as in the previous phase.

#### Neighbours, dying and reproducing

- A neighbour of a cell *a* is an another cell that is positioned next to the cell *a*, either orthogonal or diagonal.
- A neutral cell is any cell that is either `0` or `1` (isn't a bot).
- A bot cell is any cell occupied by a bot, that is, the negative number `-1` and positive `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.
- A dead cell is any cell that is exactly `0`.
- An alive cell is any cell that is not dead (`0`). This includes both bot cells and `1`'s.

In this round, cells can die. They can also reproduce.

- Neutral cells (marked `1`) will die (turn to `0`) if amount of their alive neighbours is not 2 nor 3.
- Dead cells (marked `0`) will reproduce (turn to `1`) if amount of their alive neighbours is exactly 3.

Rules about bot cells (`-1` and greater than `1`) are a bit different though.

- Bot cells will lose 1 hp if amount of their alive neighbours is not 2 nor 3 *and no natural cells were reproduced in the neighbourhood*.
- Bot cells will die if they have 0 hp.
- Bot cells will gain 1 hp if amount of their alive neighbours is equal to 3 and at least 1 neighbour is a teammate. Cell will not gain hp if it has 3 or more hp.
- Bot cells will be moved if amount of their alive neighbours is not 2 nor 3 and a single nearby cell was reproduced (it will replace it). Bot cells cannot duplicate.

#### The red zone

Every 100 generations (turns), the red zone will start in the place with most dead cells. It will end after 10 turns, and every second turn it will spawn a [glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns).

### Chatting

Bots in the same team can communicate between themselves during the game.

Some of the messages were made because of how the board is generated. Make sure you read [this](https://github.com/Soaku/KoTH-CBG/blob/master/board.md) before, so you can use it to collaborate with other bots easier.

Here's a list of all "built-in" messages:

- `1` - Help!
- `2` - Wait!
- `3` - Need healing!
- `4` - Come here
- `5` - Enemies are nearby
- `6` - I'll fight
- `7` - I'll build
- `8` - Search for boats/Build a boat
- `9` - Get in the boat
- `10` - Exit the glider

### The controller

WIP, I won't probably have time to make it this week.

### Example bot

A classic random bot, won't survive long.

```
import random


class RandomBot:

    def __init__(*args): pass

    def parachute(self, team: dict):

        return random.choice([x for x in team.values() if x])

    def start(*args):

        return random.randint(-9, 9)

    def main(*args):

        return RandomBot.start()
```

### Additional rules

- You have access only to non-superuser built-in Python packages
- You must not create, write nor open any files
- You cannot access any of internal or other bot's classes
- You cannot modify any mutable arguments given to your methods, only their copies
- You shouldn't throw any exceptions
- You must return only specified values.
- The code you publish here must not output anything

Comment: During the parachute phase, the `team[self.id]` should be that bot's last return value, and the other values should be the other teammates in the same order as their ids.

Comment: You say that bots are given Ids from 2 to 6 inclusive with a team of size 4. However, there are 5 values in the range 2 to 6 inclusive.

Comment: @KamilDrakari I noticed that earlier, but somehow didn't edit it in. Thank you!

Comment: I think it needs to be made clearer that the Game Of Life part of this challenge essentially treats all bot locations as "alive" cells. So the location of a bot is relevant for cells spontaneously becoming alive, the bot loses HP in situations where a cell would die, etc. That was the impression that I got, but it didn't immediately "click". Moving the bot if an adjacent tile reproduces and the bot would otherwise take damage is unintuitive, but I guess there's probably a good reason for it.

Comment: @KamilDrakari I edited the challenge to make it more clear. Originally, the reason for bots moving instead of taking damage was to allow the existence of vehicles, but as I look on the challenge now, I think I screwed it up, because a vehicle (glider) won't be any faster than the cell itself. Unless I increase amount of generation between turns

Comment: @Soaku I don't think having multiple generations between turns sounds fun, and it adds some extra weirdness to taking damage (either you can take damage multiple times with no way to act, or you lose the "take damage any time your cell would die" symmetry). I think losing the vehicles is a better tradeoff.

Comment: @KamilDrakari I know. So given that, the rule doesn't make any sense now.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal Squared Sums

Most everyone here is familiar with Pascal's triangle, which is formed by taking the summation of the two parent objects. Here are the first few rows:

```
     1
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
    ...
```

Let's instead rotate this to the left by 45 degrees, and assume that it's forming an infinite matrix. Alternatively, this can be thought of as the triangle is reading the anti-diagonals of the matrix.

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4
1 3 6
1 4   ...
1
```

Given an input `n`, take the top-left `n x n` sub-matrix of this infinite matrix. Then, take the column sums of that `n x n` matrix as your output.

For example, for input `n = 3`, this would result in the sub-matrix

```
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 6
```

Taking the column sums gives us `3, 6, 10`, so our output is `[3, 6, 10]`.

#### Standard I/O Boilerplate

Comment: Note that the output are just the [2~k+1]'th element on the k'th row (1-indexing)

Comment: @user202729 Really? Dang. I was hoping there was a nice relation, but I didn't expect something that simple. Hmm, maybe need to rethink this.

Comment: Neim, 6 bytes: `p₁ᛖ2` (polygonal list with side length of input, select first double input elements, remove first two elements)

Answer (score 1):

## Polyraptor/Forerunner Combo

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [mtg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg)

Notice: You probably need to understand the Stack in MTG for this challenge!

A new expansion to the trading card game [Magic: The Gathering](https://magic.wizards.com/en), *Rivals of Ixalan*, was released this January. In this set were the two cards important to this challenge: [Forerunner of the Empire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forerunner+of+the+Empire) and [Polyraptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=polyraptor), as I learned just now after losing a game of [MTG Arena](https://magic.wizards.com/en/mtgarena).

[image: Forerunner of the Empire]
[image: Polyraptor]

<sub>I like the Polyraptor in the background of Forerunner. Wizards knew precisely what they had brought about.</sub>

If you'll notice, if a Polyraptor enters the battlefield under your control, since it's a Dinosaur (look at the bit just below the art), it triggers Forerunner of the Empire's second ability. You may then have the Forerunner deal one damage to all creatures, including itself and Polyraptor! This clones Polyraptor, and the clone ALSO TRIGGERS THE ABILITY! This time, each Polyraptor (there are two now) takes one damage, and TWO new clones spring into being! However, these clone-making abilities execute one after another, not simultaneously. Both are pushed to the Stack, and the second pops and resolves. The Polyraptor clone enters the battlefield and triggers the Forerunner's ability BEFORE the second Polyraptor clone is created (Forerunner's ability pops from the Stack earlier). Again, Forerunner of the Empire deals one damage to each creature. There are now three Polyraptors, and each takes one damage. Three more Polyraptor clonings enter the Stack, which now contains four. The Forerunner, having at this point taken three damage this turn, dies, and the rest of the Polyraptors enter the battlefield without triggering its ability. When all's said and done, there are seven Polyraptors on the battlefield.

#### Generalization

Now, imagine for a moment that Forerunner had five toughness and Polyraptor three instead. Let `PA := Polyraptor-cloning ability` and `FA := One damage to all creatures`.

```
Polyraptor enters.                        Stack: FA
Forerunner deals one to each creature.    Stack: PA PA
Polyraptor enters.                        Stack: PA FA
Forerunner deals one to each creature.    Stack: PA PA PA PA
Polyraptor enters.                        Stack: PA PA PA FA
Forerunner deals one to each creature.    Stack: PA PA PA PA PA PA
  At this point, the original Polyraptor dies. It will no longer take damage. Three left.
Polyraptor enters.                        Stack: PA PA PA PA PA FA
Forerunner deals one to each creature.    Stack: PA PA PA PA PA PA PA PA
  Another Polyraptor dies. Three left.
Polyraptor enters.                        Stack: PA PA PA PA PA PA PA FA
Forerunner deals one to each creature.    Stack: PA PA PA PA PA PA PA PA PA PA
  Another Polyraptor dies. Three left.
  Forerunner also dies here.
The Stack empties with no more abilies triggered.
```

Here, the final Polyraptor count is 13.

#### Your task

Write a program or function that takes as input two nonnegative integers `F` and `P` and returns the final count of Polyraptors when a Polyraptor with toughness `P` is cast while its owner controls a Forerunner of the Empire with toughness `F`.

#### Test cases

Form: `F`, followed by `P`, followed by the result and an explanation.

```
0 0
0
The Forerunner has zero toughness, so it dies before anything happens. The Polyraptor dies immediately upon entering play.

0 5
1
As before, the Forerunner dies, but this time, the Polyraptor lives to see the dawn.

1 0
0
The Forerunner's ability triggers once, but all Polyraptors die on their own.

1 5
2
This time, the Forerunner kills itself damaging and copying the Polyraptor once.

2 5
4
Again, Forerunner kills itself, but this time, it manages to copy the Polyraptor and then both the original and the copy.

3 5
7
See above

5 3
13
See above

More coming! This is hard to do by hand :|
```

#### Rules

- Forerunner of the Empire's ability says "may". Ignore that—it always deals the damage.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) are forbidden.
- [I/O is flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884).
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) in each language wins! Happy golfing!

---

> ## Sandboxy Stuff
>
> Did I mess up a test case?
>
> What do y'all think? Should I explain the Stack so all can understand?

Comment: I think you did mess up the `5 3` test case: I get `10`, and `5 4` gives `13`. [Reference implementation](https://goo.gl/KC3puK) (goes to tio.run but I had to use a link shortener because of the limitations of comments and because I used ungolfed variable names etc.)

Comment: And on the basis of reference values, I claim that the solution is pretty straightforward by case split: using `f` and `p` respectively for Forerunner and Polyraptor toughness, it's `p == 0 ? 0 : f < p ? f*(f+1)/2+1 : p*(p+1)/2 + (f-p)*(p-1)`, where the last case can be golfed to `p*(3-p)/2+f*(p-1)`. Not sure there's enough here for an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Create a solver for the Topspin puzzle

The Topspin puzzle consists of 20 round pieces in one long looped track. The pieces can slide along the loop. There is a turntable on one of the sides of the the loop which can rotate the four adjacent pieces laying within it, so that they reverse their order.

By sliding the pieces left and right and rotating the turntable the puzzle can be scrambled.

The goal is to restore the pieces in their initital order by sliding / rotating them.

[image: Topspin]

You can learn more about the puzzle here: https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/topspin.htm

### Task:

Write a program / function that solves the Topspin puzzle from a scrambled to ordered state.

### Input:

The input is a list of the numbered scrambled pieces, in any convenient format. For example:

`10 18 12 11 7 2 3 4 6 9 15 19 14 17 1 8 13 5 20 16`

You can use 0-indexing, just mention it.

### Output:

The output is a list of moves that solve the puzzle. You a free to chose a notation which suits your language / algorithm. Possible notation:

- `0` - rotate the turntable
- `1` - slide all pieces to the left
- `2` - slide all pieces to the right

or:

- `t` - rotate the turntable
- `l` - slide all pieces to the left
- `r` - slide all pieces to the right

Since the pieces form a loop it is NOT necessary to shift the pieces in the final solution so that the lists starts at 1.

So the output should look something like this:

`011022201...` and so on

or

`tllltltrrt...`

Test cases:

`14 1 9 10 17 15 13 18 16 6 12 19 2 11 20 4 7 8 5 3
3 4 18 1 5 13 14 8 2 16 10 12 15 9 7 17 20 11 6 19
6 16 5 13 14 17 11 8 10 7 4 3 15 1 18 9 20 12 19 2`

You can use this script to generate more scrambled sequences:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BDoMwDEPv/Qr/AYxtFz5j16iH0kZaBbRRqED7@q5oLL49W46VQ31xIFvVpZDXbmMOSPnoSlzZTCN8lg/IGmVhV5Aw9OREOAVMSNYsOQuefU8G7bYjFv/Grwx3MjfQmndu2eLigsma4U@cny944jvIj1DeWTdufOZOnJZmPtBmXC/9GT0lGlMza/0C)

You can check your solution with this script: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJbcoMwDPznFHuDVlKSJhyjvx4@gJhpJk3KODQ9PjUO2DKJBz@Q1vJqJWeP46c9mmrsSnS/1xamwaUyKOBH9@Ns3X7B4WKCYRq3v9MQbMk0DYK5/NwtGgz16RtNlXl58dbteQasIQLTlnD2bt3NeszZvvW1Gzxwg6ZE3ff2ekSrroVDWJqiGusSZucfooMPtcEHyJ/9KthjC9qD30Eb0M5TJf/5vy0OVeFjG/H3ZLKHlacoYT4sHCapncNZIpIjTjL84qMYS6Kd5vsP/xJ/eYUVo2SnGbt4Ex9RHFKEdFMyDM9MJO5pLtwo3iKVC0eUjigxi6SiRF46R8p4UFSR1VspIiutROXM0ZZU44w7r1ShVRUWm7zIL@@FhMm5stIoVZmVjqL0FcXwWfNcD3rhTdFSBUh16ZqX1pAyRqQi8KoGpDJ@5kcqOq8qyapz1/@U9SplfcEqQ1YV0JXSqib1OHtFXva9Vsr7qqJ3p@uADjWa8R8)

(`a` is 1-indexed list of the scrambled pieces, `b` is the solution in notation - `1` - slide to left, `2` - slide to right, `3` - turn )

### Winning criteria:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shorest solutions in bytes in each language win. Please explain you algorithm!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there's no requirement that the solution be the shortest possible, so two moves are sufficient, and it will probably give shorter code to only use two. There's also no requirement that the program finish in any finite limit. Are both of these intentional?

Comment: @Peter Taylor Thank you for your feedback! No, they are not intentional, but my omission. In fact I was wondering how to add the length of the solution (multiplied by some coefficient < 1) to the length of the code and make the total score. I'm open for any suggestions.

Comment: can the output notation be code?

Comment: @l4m2 I'm not sure what you mean. Can you show/explain?

Comment: Combining two elements to give a single score is usually tricky. GAP finds [a solution](http://angrystatistician.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/solving-topspin-puzzle-using-gap.html) for `2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20` of length 183, so bubble sort should be able to solve an arbitrary permutation in (modulo out-by-one errors) at most `19*10+19*18/2*183 = 31483` moves. Might be worth downloading GAP and seeing what it finds for random permutations, or even whether `GrowthFunctionOfGroup` completes in a reasonable time.

Comment: @Peter Taylor Thanks! I don't have any experience with GAP, although I have it installed on my computer. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I would just try a bozo sort (and hope it works) if this question does not include the requirements of size of the solution...

Comment: @tsh This is exactly how most people try to solve puzzles :) I think I need to add a requirement that the solution should be reachable in reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

## What a hat at wheat!

Given a word, remove letters one at a time until nothing is left. Output the list of steps.

Example:

```
 wheat
 what or heat
 hat or eat
 at or ha
 a
```

All words must exist in a word list, but this list may be provided via any means, such as in a file with a specific name, or in a global variable, or built-in to the language, as long as it's a list of words and not some custom data structure. You can however require that the list is pre-sorted in a specific order (in which case you should also provide a suitable sort function, which can be in any language).

If there is more than one solution then you can return any one or all solutions. If there are no solutions then you should return a falsy value. You can assume that the input is taken from the word list. You don't need to return the original input or the empty string as part of the solution.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: [Heavily-downvoted dupe.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/145222/41024)

Comment: Technically the other one is not a duplicate target because a <Jelly> solution for this one can't be "easily" ported there...

Comment: @user202729 Yeah, the reason it's heavily downvoted is that it restricts to 4 languages.

Comment: I'd like the word list to be provided as an argument. Otherwise this is a good challenge, and a good dupe target to close the other one.

Answer (score 1):

## Softcode, take 2

**Softcoding** is an anti-pattern defined by “*the practice of removing ‘things that should be in source code’ from source code and placing them in some external resource*”, which usually are config files, database entries, or both. “*At the extreme end, soft-coded programs develop their own poorly designed and implemented scripting languages*”, as can be seen by one of the most egregious examples of the practice, the Enterprise Rules Engine.

Thus, programmers who fall to the habit of softcoding, after tons of work, find themselves at the very point they were starting from: they have developed “*some sort of **CO**mmon **B**usiness-**O**riented **L**anguage that’s generic enough to code any rule*”. But unfortunately for them, there already is such a thing. “*It’s called C++. And Java. And C#. And Basic. And, dare I say, COBOL.*”

For the sources of the above quotations are more information of the practise, see: [Soft Coding on The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Soft_Coding), [Softcoding on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) and [The Enterprise Rules Engine on The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Enterprise_Rules_Engine).

## The Challenge

**Softcode**! Make an actual, Turing-complete language that will reside in config files!

More specifically, you should write a compiler / interpreter / anything in between that will define a Turing-complete programming language, whose every valid source code will also be a valid JSON file. <sup>(The reason why JSON has been chosen is the simplicity of syntax and wide avalability of JSON parsers, so that you won't have to write a parser yourself.)</sup>

Input/output format of your JSON language is up to you.

Shortest interpreter / compiler code wins, as long as it implements a Turing-complete language.

## Technical details

Unfortunately, given how this challenge is defined, I must put one arbitrary restriction: If your language of choice supports calling a compiler or interpreter of any Turing-complete language, I must disallow doing that. Otherwise, this challenge would likely degrade to calling `eval` on a single property name of your JSON input file.

However, not to burden you with writing JSON parsers, you may use third-party libraries, as long as they're freely available. (Otherwise, good ol' C++ would be a nightmare without Boost.)

**Be creative.**

## Example interpreter

For reference, below is a simple JS interpreter of a Turing-complete JSON programming language. Of course, this code is ungolfed. <sup>(I hope there are no bugs in this interpreter, but I don't feel like testing it now.)</sup>

```js
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

// This interpreter implements GOTO-programs, which are Turing-complete.

var stdin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System['in']) );
var progsrc = stdin.readLine();
var prog = JSON.parse(progsrc).prog;

var vars = {};
vars.in = Number(stdin.readLine());

for(var i = 0; i < prog.length; i++) {
    switch(prog[i].command) {
        case 'ADD':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            vars[prog[i].varname] += prog[i].constant;
            break;
        case 'SUBSTRACT':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            vars[prog[i].varname] -= prog[i].constant;
            break;
        case 'GOTO':
            i = prog[i].index-1;
            break;
        case 'IF':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            if(vars[prog[i].varname] == prog[i].constant) {
                i = prog[i].index-1;
            }
            break;
        case 'HALT':
            i = prog.length;
            break;
    }
}

vars.out = vars.out || 0;
print(vars.out);
```

Comment: You realize that allowing `eval` make the challenge trivial. Good. Now you don't allow `eval`, we just need to implement it. The challenge degrades to "implement the 'eval' function for any Turing-complete language". Not good at all.

Comment: Looks like that it's very difficult for you to write a well-received challenge. It's unfortunate...

Comment: @user202729 You May Not Call Any Already-Existant Compiler Nor Interpreter For Any Turing-Complete Language, is this OK? How are you going to "implement eval" with such a requirement?

Comment: Just reimplement it. For some simple language, e.g., BF.

Comment: @user202729 How is implementing BF going to be shorter (in bytes) than, say, GOTO-programs, WHILE-programs or lambda calculus? BF has 8 instructions, you can do GOTO with 2

Comment: @user202729 Besides, writing a BF interpreter is an interesting golfing  challenge on its own. Figuring out which language will allow a shortest interpreter just adds more depth.

Comment: My point is, this challenge degrades to "interpret any TC language", and the "soft code" part doesn't make the problem significantly different.

Comment: And would probably be closed as duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111278/69850).

Comment: @user202729, or closed as "Too broad", as that question also should be.

Answer (score 1):

## Array-of-arrays string conversion

Matrix challenges are popular. There's an issue of how to provide test cases. A common method is the *row-wise array-of-arrays* representation, such as:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] -> a 3 by 2 matrix
```

This is good with vertical space, but there's always the task of converting the test cases into something your language can use, and vice versa for producing test cases to this format.

So this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge and also a repository of conversion functions that people can use when trying or composing matrix challenges.

### Defining the format

A **row string of length *m*** is a comma-separated list of *m ≥ 1* numbers, enclosed in square brackets.

A **row-wise *n×m* array-of-arrays string** is a comma-separated list of *n ≥ 1* **row strings of length *m*** enclosed in square brackets.

There can be no leading whitespace. One trailing newline immediately after the final `]` is optional. Otherwise any whitespace in the string is optional.

### The challenge

Produce two* programs/functions in your language:

1. one which takes a **rowwise *n×m* array-of-arrays string** as an input, and outputs the matrix (as implemented in the language.)
2. another one which takes an *n×m* matrix (as implemented in the language) as an input and outputs the **rowwise *n×m* array-of-arrays string**.

*It is allowed for one program/function to perform both tasks and you can have helper code used by both conversion functions.

### Rules

- To be clear: the language must support matrices (or something equivalent like 2D arrays - the name is not important) because the output/input of the two tasks needs to be an actual matrix in the language.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- Fewest total number of bytes (from all functions and any helper code) in each language wins.
- If one program or function does both conversions, only count those bytes once.
- Standard rules apply/loopholes forbidden.

*Here's the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16461/79980) and a [related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129136/simplify-matrix-input).*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78212/discussion-between-ngm-and-adam).

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to explicitly mention the case where the string as defined is already a valid matrix or expression in some language. And if I do need to mention this case, I don't know what the best terminology to use might be.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. I will leave it in the sandbox for another day or two in case other issues arise.

Comment: @Adám I've removed "expression" from the question.

Comment: @user202729 I've added the link to the question.

Comment: I think this one is ready to post.

Comment: I posted it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165926/array-of-array-string-conversion-to-and-from-matrix) but it was closed due to lack of clarity, and I did not make any further attempts to address the concerns due to lack of spare time at that moment. I would be open to trying again.

Answer (score 1):

## Othello Greedy Strategy

The rules for Othello can be found [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-Othello).

In a greedy strategy, in each go, you just choose a square in which to place your counter such that there are no other places that could allow you to flip more counters. However, there is still often a choice where you need to decide where to put your counter.

Given an integer N as input, when black goes first and both players follow a greedy strategy, output a possible configuration of counters at the end of the game where there are N black counters. Assume that there exists a configuration for N.

Output should be a 64-character string, where the (r-1)*8+1th to r*8th characters (inclusive) represent the rth row from left to right.

I'll add test cases if people think that this is a good challenge.

Comment: I think the core of the challenge is interesting (Implementing Othello rules).  However, I think a better way to present it is to give them a board, and have them output a greedy move.

Comment: I think you should add the rules in your post (challenges should be self-contained)

Comment: Although the challenge is interrsting, I have no idea how can I solve this in a teasonable time. NathanMerrill's suggestionis better.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

### A sort of cyclic program to string together

Write a program that sorts a string.

However, it does some other things too:

1. When given a non-sorted string (that is not your source code), outputs the string in non-descending ASCII code order, as expected.
2. When given a sorted string, outputs your program's source code but sorted.
3. When given your source code but sorted, outputs the original source code.
4. When given your source code (not sorted), outputs any nonempty string that is none of the above outputs

   - i.e. Your program cannot output a sorted string and therefore must be at least two characters, and it cannot output your original source code

---

As a result, consider `input string -> output string`. If you're starting with any non source code unsorted string:

- The program will start with `given unsorted string -> given string sorted`. This sorted string can then be input to your program again resulting in `given string sorted -> source code sorted`
- If you continue to inputting what the program produced as output, it will then cycle through `source code sorted -> source code -> chosen unsorted string -> chosen string sorted -> source code sorted`.

---

### Example

Let your program be `foobar`. Consider the following examples:

```
-- Case 1 (unsorted string -> sorted string) --

Input:  Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
Output:     &CGPPadeefggillmmnooorrsuzz

Input:  
This is an unsorted string
Hey look a newline
Output: 

       HTaadeeeeghiiiikllnnnnnooorrssssttuwy

-- Case 2 (sorted string -> sorted source code) --

Input:  123ABCDabcd
Output: abfoor

Input:      &CGPPadeefggillmmnooorrsuzz
Output: abfoor

Input:  a
Output: abfoor

-- Case 3 (sorted source code -> unsorted source code) --

Input:  abfoor
Output: foobar

-- Case 4 (unsorted source code -> unsorted string) --

Input:  foobar
Output: a1
```

Using the last example, if your program outputs `a1` as your chosen string, then it will continue to cycle through `a1 -> 1a -> abfoor -> foobar -> a1`.

---

### Specifications

- Input and output are both strings
- Your source code can't already be in sorted order since there are two different actions depending on whether or not it is sorted
- Standard I/O methods apply and standard loopholes forbidden
- This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins

---

### Sandbox

Usually I have some sort of solution for a challenge but I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this. I liked the idea though and wanted to know if it's original and if it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Reverse Engineering RNG

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [random-number-generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number-generator)

---

## Intro to both

Pseudorandom number generators are used for simulation and security. While most are appropriate for games and simulations (appropriateness depends on statistical properties), only a select few algorithms are appropriate for security because most of the others are too predictable and can introduce severe vulnerabilities. This challenge should (hopefully) demonstrate how easily some algorithms can be cracked and why the choice of RNG algorithm matters for security.

---

## Cops

Choose/implement/create a pseudorandom number generator, seed it with a constant state, generate the first 10,000 32-bit unsigned integers, and link to it from your post. The robbers will be trying to make a program that generates the same sequence.

Your post should include:

- The total number of bits of state used by the generator. For example the well-known [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) has 19,937 bits of state.

  - Note that if you're using multiple RNG algorithms together, you will have to show the combined count of bits of state.
  - Any randomness used to seed the generator does not count toward this value, though the seed must be constant.
- A link to the generated sequence of 32-bit unsigned integers

*DO NOT* post the source code of your generator. That's what the robbers are trying to figure out.

A submission is considered "cracked" if a robber has made a program that generates the exact same sequence. *Therefore it is necessary that a robber determine not only the algorithm, but also the initial state of your generator*

### "Bits of State" Explanation

Every random number generator has a state that is used to determine the next number in the sequence and every number thereafter. Each time a number is used, the state is convoluted in some way and a random number is emitted. The minimum number of binary bits required to store this state will be your "bits of state" count. If you were using a 32-bit [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), you would have 32 bits of state. If you were using an LCG with a modulus of 123,456,789, you would have 27 bits of state because 27 bits is the minimum number of bits required to represent every integer between 0 and 123,456,788, inclusive, even if such a state would actually be stored on a 32-bit integer.

### Rules and Scoring

- All state must be self-contained within your generator and your program should generate the exact same sequence every time it is run.
- You may not use *any* external sources of entropy, including uninitialized memory, wall time, input, atmospheric noise, network latency, etc...
- If using an existing algorithm, you will need to make sure to do your research to ensure that the generator meets the above requirements. You may need to seed it manually to ensure that.
- There are no statistical restrictions on your sequence: it does not have to pass any statistical tests and can fit any distribution you would like, so long as it fits within the range of an unsigned 32-bit integer.
- The source code to the program used to generate your sequence cannot be larger than 4 KB.
- A submission that has not been cracked in 168 hours (1 week) will be considered "safe".
- The "safe" submission with the fewest number of bits of state is the winner.

---

## Robbers

Choose a Cop submission from the other thread (link) and crack its random number generator. It will be considered cracked if you can recreate the sequence exactly.

### Rules and Scoring

- Hard-coding the sequence is not allowed.
- Your program is limited to 4KB
- Your generator does not need to have the same state size as long as it generates the same sequence. In practice, this will be necessary unless the RNG used is a really bad algorithm.
- For each successful crack of a not-yet-safe random number sequence, you will score points according to the number of bits of state used by the generator:

  - 1-32 bits: 1 point
  - 33-128 bits: 2 points
  - 129-1024 bits: 3 points
  - 1025-8192 bits: 5 points
  - 8193-65536 bits: 8 points
  - More than 65536 bits: 13 points

Comment: How would one link a black-box function?

Comment: @JoKing I'm not quite sure how this is supposed to work. I'm going to have to read up on c&r challenges.

Comment: Can you give an objective definition of "*non-cryptographically-secure PRNG algorithm*"?

Comment: It seems the algprithm itself can use the seed xor-ed, so giving seed known is useless; but then it's quite bad

Comment: @l4m2 That's a good point

Comment: How do "bits of state" work?

Comment: "*A submission is considered "cracked" if a robber has made a program that generates the exact same sequence. Therefore it is necessary that a robber determine not only the algorithm, but also the initial state of your generator*" I don't think so. As I read the question, the robber's generator only has to agree with the cop's for the first 320000 bits output, but unlike the cop the robber has no size limit, so they can hard-code the full 320000 bits. "*Hard-coding the sequence is not allowed*" is not an objective restriction.

Comment: Cop: have an n-bit counter, take the kth byte of sha(MAGIC + counter++). n=12 if you want to bet that the robber can't compress the stream at all; otherwise n=13. The existence of crypto breaks most C&R ideas, but excluding it objectively is tough, and IMO this is a fairly fundamental problem with C&R.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's actually a good point there. I hadn't thought of using a salted hash. That is a trivial "RNG" algorithm that is pretty much unbreakable. I could hard-ban crypto, but there's no way of verifying that and I already have enough on the honor system for cops. *sigh*

Comment: There is some sense in which RNG *is* crypto: a seedable RNG can be used as a stream cipher, although it might not be a good one.

Comment: So a 1-in-3 and a 1-in-5 is 4 bit or 5 bit?

Comment: @l4m2 I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

<sup><sup>[Asked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166594/interpreted-arithmetic)</sup></sup>

Comment: Having posted and edited to just contain a link, you can also delete.

Answer (score 1):

## Add least char to match

Given a string, add at least chars to make the whole string match the given regexp. You can assume it's possible. If there are more than one solution, output a (not necessary uniform) random one.

Here regexp may contain:

```
|  or
() group
?  possibly not appear
*  may appear for any times. Maybe different in each match
0  
1
```

Samples

```
0100      (01)*         010101
0         (0|1)(0|1)    00; 01; 10 (any should possibly appear)
1010      ((0|1)(0|1))* 1010
101       ((0|1)(0|1))* 1010; 1011; 1001; 0101; 1101
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex)

Comment: Suggested question text for first para: "Given a string of 0s and 1s, and a regexp: add the minimum number of characters (0s and 1s) that makes the whole string match the given regexp. You can assume that this is possible. If there are multiple solutions of the same length, output any one of them." (This is meant to be a rewording of the same conditions, let me know if I've changed the task in some way with this wording.)

Comment: @sundar Well I did only implied that the string can only contain `0` and `1`, 2) I required random, though it may leads to lots of quite strange solutions(generate one that fit, generate another string of same length, if not match return the sure one)

Comment: " I did only implied that the string can only contain 0 and 1, 2" <- Are you saying that `2` is also allowed? I don't understand what you're saying here.

" I required random, though it may leads to lots of quite strange solutions" <- Can you explain what you mean by random here, exactly? Your sample test case says "any should possibly appear", and that's what my proposed text says at the end ("not necessarily uniform random" seems to be a complicated way of saying the same thing).

Comment: `2)` meant it's the second point. "output any of them" seems it can be determistic as the result is valid @sundar

Answer (score 1):

## Draw the Recamán's Sequence

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Recamán's sequence ([A005132](http://oeis.org/A005132)) is a mathematical sequence, defined as such:

```
A(0) = 0
A(n) = A(n-1) - n if A(n-1) - n > 0 and is new, else
A(n) = A(n-1) + n
```

A pretty LaTex version of the above (might be more readable):

[image: pretty latex]

The first few terms are `0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11`

(Description of the sequence borrowed from [this older question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/generaterecam%c3%a1ns-sequence)).

Your task is to *animate* the drawing this sequence as a series of semi-circles:

[image: Sequence construction]

Where each entry above is a keyframe in the animation. Tween frames should draw the circle segment, and if necessary, scale the image down when the new locus would be out of frame.

After 600 terms of the sequence you should have something like this:
[image: Pattern]
(Image from [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGC5TdIiT9U&t=496s))

Your choice whether to draw horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, provided that the entire image fits within the image boundary. Line color can be any value, background can be any value (values must be distinct).

## Winner

- The program to generate the *most* terms of the sequence wins (before the program terminates, crashes, or otherwise corrupts the output--eg by exceeding file size limitations<sup>1</sup>).
- Tie will go to the *shorter* program.

## Rules

- Output image size shall be no smaller than 2048x2048, compiled as a gif, apng, common video format (e.g. mp4), or as an HTML or Javascript canvas (in-place animation).
- Segments should be drawn over 0.5 second intervals
- Frame Rate should be no slower than 24 frames/second
- (That is, each term of the sequence will take at least 12 frames to draw)
- You need not embed the *entire* output in your answer, although some means of showing off the results of your work is expected (sped up version, choice stills, etc).

1 <sub>If your program will happily produce files in excess of 128 MB (the 64 bit NTFS file system will allow up to 16 TB files), post an altered version of your program that terminates after approximately 128 MB to avoid trashing people's hard drives. You may score based on the unaltered bytecount. Do please post a still image of the final frame your program *could otherwise produce* (within reason: you not required to generate the entire animation in order to determine true termination). You may use a modified / separate program to produce this still, as it is purely for aesthetic and curiosity purposes.</sub>

Comment: `before the program terminates, crashes, or otherwise corrupts the output--eg by exceeding file size limitations ... Segments should be drawn over 0.5 second intervals. Frame Rate should be no slower than 24 frames/second` These requirements are heavily dependent on the machine that one uses and therefore are difficult to measure objectively without a person testing every solution; i.e. you, the challenge poster, will have to run all submissions.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: too many rules about time limits, output format, etc, imho

Answer (score 1):

## Binary Positional Average

## Introduction

(This challenge is from work today)
This challenge seems relevant for actual use in the real world, it's a (as far as i know) not yet dealt with kind of integer sequences.

## Challenge

- Inputs: A Integer between 1 and 64 representing the amount of bits to iterate through
- Output: An Array or a delimiter separated sequence of arrays or sequences of 0s and 1s

The algorithm has to take the input and generate all binary sequences up to the given number ordered by the position of the average 1 bit in the binary representation of the current number.
The direction of the sorting is irrelevant.
0 can be ignored.

The solution must terminate, otherwise this is code golf, tiebreaker is performance in program steps.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 4

Has (among others) the following possible outputs:

> 0001,0011,0101,0010,0111,1011,0110,1111,0000,1001,1101,1110,1010,0100,1100,1000

Or:

> 0001,0011,0111,0010,0101,1011,0110,1111,1001,1101,1010,1110,0100,1100,1000

## Example Implementation

(Javascript - modified sketch from work)

```
function binaryPositionalAverage(size) {

    let srMap = [];

    for (let i = 2**size -1; i > 0; i--) {

        let inp = (i).toString(2);
        let out = "";
        // pad with 0s
        for (let i = 0; i < (size - inp.length); i++) {
            out += "0";
        }
        out += inp;
        out = out.split("").map(s => parseInt(s));
        // out format: [1,1,1,1];

        let rating = 0;
        let divisor = 0; // we ignore 0 by loop condition
        for (let k = 0; k < out.length; k++) {
            if (out[k]) {
                rating += k+1;
                divisor++;
            }
        }
        rating /= divisor;

        srMap.push({
            rating: rating,
            binary: out,
        });
    }
    return srMap.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating).map(e => e.binary);
}
```

Comment: I find the description rather confusing because of the way it switches between talking about numbers and binary sequences without warning, but I'm pretty sure that the second example output is wrong. Ordering from `0001` to `1000` the order must begin `0001,0011`. Then `0010,0101,0111` in any order; then `1011`; then `0110,1001,1111` in any order, then `1101`; then `0100,1010,1110` in any order; and finally `1100,1000`. Plus `0000` somewhere if desired.

Comment: @PeterTaylor you are right sir, the second output is wrong
I'll go ahead and rewrite the challenge later this afternoon to talk about binary representation of numbers, and provide a reference implementation

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe but can't quite come up with the right search terms to find it.

Comment: @Shaggy I'm not sure, weather i should react to this comment. If the challenge is a dupe, please provide some kind of proof, and I'll delete it; On another note: How would you improve it?

Comment: Does `0 can be ignored` mean that **0** can be sorted anywhere in the sequence? Or does it mean that it can be omitted, but if it is included it should be sorted as in the example?

Comment: What do you mean by `The solution must terminate`. Only that it can't get stuck in an infinite loop, or do it need to finish for `n = 64` within a specific amount of time on a specific set of hardware? I presume it is the former as generating and sorting `18446744073709551616` strings will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

### Execute a Subpar Shuffle™

Inspired by the [Execute a Superb Shuffle™](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166999/execute-a-superb-shuffle) challenge, and a shuffling method I used as a young child before I realised how bad (and time consuming) it is.

In a Subpar Shuffle, you take the deck of cards, and perform the following actions:

1. Take the top card of the deck and deal it out into a pile.
2. Take the next card of the deck and place it underneath the deck.
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 until you've dealt out the whole deck.

If your deck is represented as a list, then it looks something like this:

1. Set up an empty list to hold the shuffled list.
2. Put the first item of the old list at the start of the new list.
3. Put the first item of the old list at the end of the old list.
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until the old list is empty, then return the new list.

So, for example, the input list [1, 2, 3, 4] would result in the following:

```
Old list     | New list
[1, 2, 3, 4] | []
[2, 3, 4]    | [1]          Put the 1 at the start of the new list
[3, 4, 2]    | [1]          Put the 2 at the end of the old list
[4, 2]       | [3, 1]       Put the 3 at the start of the new list
[2, 4]       | [3, 1]       Put the 4 at the end of the old list
[4]          | [2, 3, 1]    Put the 2 at the start of the new list
[4]          | [2, 3, 1]    Put the 4 at the end of the old list
[]           | [4, 2, 3, 1] Put the 4 at the start of the new list
```

So the final Subpar Shuffled list is [4, 2, 3, 1].

Here are a few more test results for Subpar Shuffling of various lists:

```
Input                     | Output
[]                        | []
["Ace of Spades"]         | ["Ace of Spades"]
["A","c","e","o","f","S"] | ["o","S","c","f","e","A"]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]     | [4,8,0,6,2,9,7,5,3,1]
```

Comment: Will we be guaranteed that each element in the input list is unique?

Comment: That's a fair question. I think that for the purpose of this challenge, I would say yes (although I don't see that it makes much difference).

Answer (score 1):

## A fast-growing evaluator

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

### Introduction

The fast-growing hierarchy is a hierarchy of, well, fast-growing functions, with a one-to-one correspondence to ordinals. If you did some [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver) challenges, you may have worked with them, since it's a systematic means of defining functions with extremely fast growth rates.

Here, you are defining as many of them as you can. Of course, because of obvious problems with enumerating them sequentially, the challenge is to yield any particular one given the ordinal, up to as far an upper limit as possible.

### The fast-growing hierarchy

If you are lost on some of the jargon here, I recommend a read about ordinals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

The fast growing hierarchy is defined for each ordinal in a recursive manner as follows:

- The lowest and slowest function, corresponding to 0, is f<sub>0</sub>(n) = n+1.

  - f<sub>0</sub>(3) = 3+1 = 4
- For succeeding ordinals and functions in the hierarchy, f<sub>a+1</sub>(n) = f<sub>a</sub><sup>n</sup>(n).

  - f<sub>1</sub>(2) = f<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>(2) = f<sub>0</sub>(f<sub>0</sub>(2)) = f<sub>0</sub>(3) = 4
- For functions in the hierarchy corresponding to limit ordinals, first determine a fundamental sequence that approaches the ordinal in question. Then, f<sub>a</sub>(n) = f<sub>a[n]</sub>(n), where a[n] is the nth ordinal in the fundamental sequence.

  - The fundamental sequence of ω is {0, 1, 2, 3...}, indexing from zero. So f<sub>ω</sub>(2) = f<sub>2</sub>(2) = f<sub>1</sub>(f<sub>1</sub>(2)) = f<sub>1</sub>(4) = 8

As can be seen, for infinite-ordinal entries of the fast-growing hierarchy, the value of the function is dependent on the choice of fundamental sequences. Most ordinal notations specify fundamental sequences with the ordinals that they define notations for.

Here are some typical choices of ordinal notations and fundamental sequences, arranged in increasing ordinal-notating capability:

- [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form), for which [The Wainer hierarchy](http://cantorsattic.info/Fast-growing_hierarchy) defines fundamental sequences
- [The Veblen functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function)
- [Madore's ordinal collapsing function](http://cantorsattic.info/Madore%27s_%CF%88_function)
- [Buchholz's ordinal collapsing functions](http://cantorsattic.info/Buchholz%27s_%CF%88_functions)
- [Jager's ordinal collapsing functions](http://cantorsattic.info/J%C3%A4ger%27s_collapsing_functions_and_%CF%81-inaccessible_ordinals)

### The challenge

Within 1024 bytes, write a program that takes the string representation of an ordinal A in some ordinal interval starting at 0, and a number B of arbitrary size, and prints the fast-growing function corresponding to A, applied to B.

- Choices of domain of representation, ordinal domain, ordinal notation, and ordinal fundamental sequences must be specified. The choice of fundamental sequences must actually approach the ordinals they define fundamental sequences to, such that logically, the ωth ordinal of that sequence would be the ordinal of that fundamental sequence.
- The program must provably halt for any input, given sufficient resources, even for invalid inputs or inputs corresponding to ordinals beyond the program's capability. In particular, raw eval() of the input is forbidden, and entries are disqualified if they permit arbitrary code execution.
- For all given ordinals with the program's capability, the program must print the value as described above for all numbers, deterministically, given enough resources.
- Standard restrictions on running time and resource usage of programs are relaxed.
- Competing entries must be able to handle at least A=0.

### Scoring

Take C to be the first ordinal for which the program fails to satisfy the requirements above, and D to be the difference between your program byte length and 1024, the maximum byte length of submissions. Then your score is C+D.

Sample scores:

- Alice, in 200 bytes, writes a program for which A can be any natural number. Her score is ω+824.
- Bob, in 220 bytes, writes a program for which A can be ω or any natural number. His score is (ω+1)+804 = ω+805.
- Carol, in 400 bytes, writes a program for which A can be any ordinal purely in Cantor normal form. Her score is ε<sub>0</sub>+624.
- Dave, in 700 bytes, writes a program for which A can be a natural number or any epsilon number. His score is ω+324.
- Eve, in 300 bytes, writes a program which segfaults if A is represented by a decimal string longer than 65536 bytes. Her score is 10<sup>65536</sup>+724.

Comment: We already have mathjax...

Comment: @user202729 The challenge is around making a program that can do as asked, to as far a scale as its resources can handle. Of course no computer can have truly infinite resources, but it's the effort to get there that I'm aiming for. The allowance for people to specify their own input, up to reasonable bounds, is to let people specify the infinite ordinals in finite space, say by using the greek letter omega to represent its corresponding ordinal.

Comment: However...... you can make your program work for all computable ordinal by make (the notation of an ordinal) = (the function which when given \$n\$ returns the \$n^{th}\$ element in one of its fundamental sequence if it's a limit ordinal, else something contains its pred).

Comment: The key words are "given enough resources". A program that uses large arrays may choke on a microcontroller but function just fine on a desktop and a supercomputer, and can be designed so it functions essentially the same in the latter two cases, and naturally scales for bigger requirements given more resources. No one will have enough resources to create a computer that can work with some of the hugest defineable numbers, but that doesn't stop people from creating challenges where outputting such huge numbers is the goal of the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Assign tasks to processors [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)<sup><sup><sup>anything better to put here?</sup></sup></sup>

Given a list of processor speeds \$S\$, where each element denotes how many ticks the processor at its index takes to complete a task, and a number of tasks \$N\$, replace every element in \$S\$ with the number of tasks the processor at its index should perform. The order of completion doesn't matter, and the tasks aren't enumerated anyway. The processors you pick don't matter either. The only thing that matters is that the ticks needed to complete all the tasks are the least possible. If there are multiple solutions, choose one with the lowest sum of the ticks each processor spends working (less man-hours means happier workers). This is a simple version of such a challenge, so you can assume that every task takes the same amount of time to be completed. You can assume that \$S\$ only consists of positive integers and that its length is at least \$1\$, and \$N\$ is a non-negative integer. <sup>What a blob of text...</sup>

#### Examples (test cases)

\$S=[4,1,3,1,2,2,1,1]\\N=13\\\text{Example output: }[0,3,0,3,1,0,3,3]\$

\$S=[8]\\N=28\\\text{Example output: }[28]\$

\$S=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]\\N=5\\\text{Example output: }[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]\$

\$S=[1,28]\\N=28\\\text{Example output: }[28,0]\$
Note that \$[27,1]\$ is an invalid output, since \$1\times27+28\times1>1\times28\$.

Comment: Can I output work time of each processor? (speed × number of work)

Comment: @Emigna `[0, 2, 0, 3, 0]` is also invalid. There's `[0, 2, 0, 2, 1]` which completes all the tasks in 2 ticks, while yours does so only after 3 ticks. The lowest sum is only a tiebreaker, and, if there are still ties, you can choose any possible output. I guess that's not clear enough.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, no. It does make some sense, but I don't want a multiple-output challenge.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Ah, right.

Answer (score 1):

## Integers in increasing order of width when printed in Helvetica

[image: XKCD 2016]

According to Explain XKCD, Helvetica kerns adjacent `1`s together slightly. This means that the sequence of integers in increasing order of width is `(0, )` `1,` `2,` `3,` `4,` `5,` `6,` `7,` `8,` `9,` `11,` `10,` `12 ... 99,` `111,` `110,` `112 ... 119,` `211,` `311,` `411,` `511,` `611,` `711,` `811,` `911,` `100 ... 109,` `120 ... 210,` etc.

For the purposes of this question you can assume that repunits will always print wider than numbers with fewer digits. Note that the adjacent pairs may overlap e.g. `11011` has the same width as `11100`.

Given an integer `n`, either return the `n`th integer in the sequence (you may but do not need to support the `0`th integer as `0`) or the first `n` integers (starting at either `0` or `1`). Alternatively, print the sequence indefinitely or return a generator or equivalent lazy list.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

(Should I include negative integers? They could be assumed to be longer than all positive integers with the same number of digits, but shorted than those with more digits.)

Comment: From explain xkcd: "This sequence is not uniquely defined" ...? Also which is longer, 30 1's or 29 2's?

Comment: @user202729 "For the purposes of this question you can assume that repunits will always print wider than numbers with fewer digits."

Comment: Still, what about 1111110 and 222220? Both are not repdigits.

Comment: @user202729 Well, you already know you can assume 111111 is wider than 22222...

Comment: So what? 1 is not shorter than 2, but 11 is shorter than 22. Exactly what are we supposed to do?

Comment: @user202729 Sort by length and by number of pairs of adjacent 1s.

Comment: I think you should state explicitly that numbers should be first sorted by number of digits then by number of consecutive `1`s (if I understood correctly and that is true).

Comment: my suggestions. 1. explain what a 'repunit' is. 2. explain what 'kerning' is, actually 3. give a basic explanation of how typesetting works in a computer and how something like this can be measured. 3. specify non-negative integers. 4. is it true that all numbers in helvetica have same width except 1?

Answer (score 1):

## Play a Game of Balls Bounce

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

The game [Balls Bounce](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ballz.brick.breaker.ballz.bounce.free) consists of the following:

- a number of blocks, each containing a \$durability\$ number \$\geq 1\$
- a field of dimension \$h \times w\$, partially filled with blocks (field is \$9\times 7\$ in the example)
- a number of \$balls\$, positioned in one location at the bottom of the field

Rules of the game:

- The player chooses a direction in which all the balls will be shot sequentially.
- Each time a ball hits a block, that block's \$durability\$ decreases by \$1\$.
- A block that has its \$durability\$ decreased below \$1\$ is removed from the field.
- Balls that hit a block are deflected and continue to fly. Note that one ball may be deflected multiple times and hit the same block more than once.
- Balls do not interact with each other directly. They may be in the same place at the same time.
- If a ball touches the top, left, or right side of the field, it gets deflected in a similar manner.
- If a ball touches the bottom of the field, it gets stuck there and won't continue to fly this round.
- A round ends once there are no more balls flying around.
- After a round ends, all blocks on the field move one row downwards, and new blocks spawn in the top row.
- **The player loses if any block goes past the bottom line.**

Note that \$balls\$ might be higher than \$durability\$ of the first block that is hit. In that case, the player now has to keep to paths in mind: the first, a \$durability\$ amount of balls, is deflected by the block, while the second, a \$durability - balls\$ amount passes through the position where the now destroyed block once was.

In the mobile game, the player can choose some angle for the shot. Because I want to make this challenge not bigger than it already is, there is only three possible angles to choose from: 45° to the left, denoted by \$L\$, straight upwards, denoted by \$U\$, and 45° to the right, denoted by \$R\$. Also, the first ball to touch the bottom line marks the position from which the nex round's shot will be taken. For simplicity's sake, all shots will be taken from the middle of the baseline. If a grid has even \$w\$, left of the middle is chosen. If an ambiguity would be created by two balls interacting with the same block at once, the ball that was shot first interacts first.

### Input

- #### The Field with Blocks

  You may take this as a \$h \times w\$ 2D array of integers or strings. Each value represents the \$durability\$ of the block at that position. You may choose something other than \$0\$ to represent an empty space.
- #### The Amount of Balls

  Quite self-explanatory. Integer (or any convenient format).
- #### The Direction

  One of \$\{L, U, R\}\$. You may choose the three strings `"L"`, `"U"` ,`"R"` to represent this, but any three distinct and consistent values will suffice.

### Output

- #### Is the game over?

  Output a truthy value if the game is lost after this round, and a falsy one if the game can go on. Any two distinct and consitent values will suffice.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

### Example:

**Input:**

Field

```
[0][0][0][0][0]
[0][9][0][0][0]
[0][0][1][0][1]
[0][0][0][2][0]
```

Balls `3`

Direction `"R"`

**Output:**

`False`

**Step-by-step:**

```
-----------------------
          (1)
-----------------------
#######################   #  border of field
#+---+---+---+---+---+#   
#|   |   |   |   |   |#   +  corner of block/empty cell
#+---+---+---+---+---+#   -  horizontal border of block/empty cell
#|   | 9 |   |   |   |#   |  vertical border of block/empty cell
#+---+---+---+---+---+#   
#|   |   | 1 |   | 1 |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   | 2 |   |#   2  durability
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
###########o###########   o  ball
           3              3  number of balls remaining to be shot

-----------------------
          (2)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   | 9 |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   | 1 |   | 1 |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   o 1 |   |#      the first block is hit, durability decreased to 1
#+---+---+--/+---+---+#   /  "tail" to show the direction of the ball
###########o###########
           2

-----------------------
          (3)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   | 9 |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   | 0 |   | 1 |#      second block decreased to 0, ball that hit it is deflected
#+---+---+-o-+---+---+#
#|   |   |   o 0 |   |#      same for the first block
#+---+---+--/+---+---+#
###########o###########
           1

-----------------------
          (3)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   | 9 |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   | 1 |#       
#+---+---+-o-+---+---+#
#|   |   o   o   |   |# 
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
###########-###########
           0

-----------------------
          (4)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   | 9 |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   o   |   | 1 |#       
#+---+---+---+-o-+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |# 
#+---+-o-+---+---+---+#      first ball hit the bottom line...
###########-###########
           0

-----------------------
          (5)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   | 8 |   |   |   |#
#+---+-o-+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   o 0 |#       
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |# 
#+---+---+---+---+---+#      ... and is removed subsequently
###########-###########
           0

-----------------------
       (6 to 19)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+-*-+---+---+---+#      *  path of the right ball
#|   *   *   |   |   |#
#+-*-+---+-*-+---+---+#
#*   | 8 |   *   |   |#
#+-*-+---+---+-o-+---+#
#|   o   |   |   |   |#      °  path of the left ball
#+-°-+-*-+---+---+---+#
#°   |   *   |   |   |# 
#+-°-+---+-*-+---+---+#
###########-###########
           0

-----------------------
          (20)
-----------------------
#######################
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#
#+---+---+---+---+---+#
#|   |   |   |   |   |#      all balls are gone, blocks are shifted down
#+---+-V-+---+---+---+#      no block reaches the bottom line, so no game over
#|   | 8 |   |   |   |#       
#+---+---+---+---+---+#      Return false
#|   |   |   |   |   |# 
#+---+---+---+---+---+#      
###########-###########
           0
```

The step-by-step diagram is just for illustrative purposes. You are not required to print any of the above.

---

## Sandbox Questions

As this is my first challenge on here, I need some guidance. What examples should be added to clarify the task? What corner cases hould I take into consideration? And most importantly, is it clear what my challenge will be?

Comment: What happens if a ball hits a corner of a block rather than a side?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork This is not possible, since the ball always starts in the middle of the bottom of the bottom line's center cell, and move diagonally or vertically. Only the middles of a cell's sides can be hit this way. Should I add an illustration to clarify this? In the original game, if a ball hit a block exactly on the corner, it would be reflected in the opposite direction it came from, taking its path back. I can add this rule, but it should never occur with angles constrained to {45, 90, 135} degrees.

Comment: Then maybe just a sentence saying "The ball is guaranteed to never hit a block on the corner." or something, just to completely rule it out. I get what you're saying with the angles, and that makes sense now that I read it again, but it'd be good to have definitive clarification. Nice challenge, otherwise!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Ill think about a way to rephrase my rules so this becomes more clear. Will add your suggestion later when I'm home :) Thank you.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I couldn't think of any corner cases that might come up. Do you have ideas for that?

Comment: Corner cases would be things like: A block that can't be reached directly but requires a ricochet to hit, a block by itself on the field, a block that if not hit will result in a game over (that's covered in your example), a field with two blocks that will cause a game over and the balls can only hit one, etc. I would recommend guaranteeing that an empty field will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

## Drawing a convex polyiamond [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [polyomino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyomino)

A subtask of [Drawing convex polyiamonds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168679). I consider the drawing part hard enough on itself.

A [polyiamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyiamond) is a polygon made from equilateral triangles. For example: (example in ASCII art)

```
  *
 / \
*---*
```

Or:

```
  *---*
 / \ / \
*---*---*
 \ /
  *
```

(with lines drawn between the triangles for clarity)

While the first polyiamond is convex, the second one is not.

---

Consider a convex polyiamond. All of its internal angles must be less than 180°. Also, the internal angle of a triangle is 60°, so each vertex must be 60° or 120°.

Assume a polyiamond has all 120° angles. It must have 6 edges.

Given the length of those 6 edges, it's either possible to reconstruct the polyiamond uniquely, or there are no such polyiamond. For example:

```
(1,1,1,1,1,1) ->

  *---*
 / \ / \
*---*---*
 \ / \ /
  *---*

(1,2,1,2,1,2) ->

  *---*---*
 / \ / \ / \
*---*---*---*
 \ / \ / \ /
  *---*---*
   \ / \ /
    *---*
```

---

Now consider a 60° internal angle. It can be assumed to be two consecutive 120° angle with the intermediate edge have length 0. For example:

```
(0,1,0,1,0,1) ->

  *
 / \
*---*
```

---

Your program should take a list of 6 non-negative integers (in any convenient format such as: tuples, string of comma-separated integers, \$2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d 11^e 13^f\$ (for Fractran?)) which represents a valid convex polyiamond, and output the polyiamond as ASCII art.

It's guaranteed that:

- No numbers in the list will exceed 12.
- It's guaranteed that there is at least 1 cell in the output. (so `(0,0,1,0,0,1)` is not a valid input) Equivalently, no two consecutive `0`'s can appear in the input list.

Comment: Please upvote this comment if you think the challenge is ready to be posted on main.

Comment: Please upvote the post if you think the challenge is interesting, and downvote the post if you think the challenge is not interesting. If the post has enough downvotes I will not post it.

Comment: Please upvote this comment (or just leave a comment) if you think the challenge has something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: *I have to leave the comments above because it may be unclear how voting in the sandbox works.*

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of variable names and a list of monomials, output a string representation of the name of the polynomial. The monomials should be represented as pairs `[coefficient, vector of exponents]` where the vector of exponents has the same length as the list of variable names.

Combine like terms, omit terms that have coefficient zero, and output the resulting polynomial.

If the list of variables is `["x", "y", "z"]` then `[c, [i,j,k]]` represents the monomial `c*x^iy^jz^k`, so for example `[2, [1,2,3]]` should be printed as `2xy^2z^3` and `[-1, [0,1,2]]` should be printed as `-yz^2`.

### A worked example:

Input `["x","y"], [[4,[2,1]], [1,[0,0]], [-1,[1,1]],[-2,[2,1]]]`: 
The monomial `[2,1]` which corresponds to `x^2y` is repeated twice, `[4,[2,1]]` with coefficient `4` and `[-2,[2,1]]` with coefficient `-2` so we add those two coefficients together to get `2x^2y`.

`[1,[0,0]]` corresponds to `1x^0y^0` which should be displayed as `1` and `[-1,[1,1]]` corresponds to `-1x^1y^1` which should be displayed as `-xy`. The polynomial is the sum of these three, so all together the output should be `2x^2y - xy + 1` or some reordering of these terms.

### Requirements:

- Operators can be surrounded in spaces
- Like terms should be combined.
- If the exponent is 1 it should be omitted: `x`, not `x^1`. If the exponent is zero, the variable should be omitted entirely: `y` not `x^0y` and `1` not `x^0y^0`.
- Empty polynomials should be represented as 0.
- Terms with coefficient zero should be dropped. A coefficient of `1` should be omitted unless all exponents are zero.
- A negative coefficient should be written with a minus sign. If the first monomial has a positive coefficient, it should not be preceded by a `+`.
- Terms can be output in any order

### Test Cases

```
Input: ["x"], [] ==> "0"
Input: [], [[3,[]], [-7,[]]] ==> "- 4"
Input: ["x"], [[0,[5]]] ==> "0"
Input: ["x"], [[1,[5]]] ==> "x^5"
Input: ["x"], [[-1,[5]]] ==> "- x^5"
Input: ["x"], [[1,[5]], [1,[5]]] ==> "2x^5"
Input: ["x"], [[1,[5]], [-1,[5]]] ==> "0"
Input: ["x"], [[1,[2]], [2,[1]], [3,[0]]] ==> "3 + 2x + x^2"
Input: ["x"], [[3,[0]], [2,[1]], [1,[2]]] ==> "3 + 2x + x^2"
Input: ["x", "y", "z"], [[1,[0,0,1]], [1,[1,0,0]], [-1,[0,1,0]]] ==> "x - y + z"
Input: ["x_1", "x_2"], [[1,[1,1]],[1,[2,2]]] ==> "x_1x_2 + x_1^{2}x_2^{2}"
Input: ["x", "y"], [[2,[2,2]], [3,[2,1]], [4,[2,0]], [1,[0,0]], [-1,[1,0]],[-2,[2,0]]] ==> 
        "1 - x + 2x^2 + 3x^2y + 2x^2y^2"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lord Vetinari's Clock

> Someone very clever — certainly someone much cleverer than whoever had
> trained that imp — must have made the clock for the Patrician’s waiting
> room. It went tick-tock like any other clock. But somehow, and against
> all usual horological practice, the tick and the tock were irregular.
> Tick tock tick ... and then the *merest* fraction of a second longer
> before ... tock tick tock ... and then a tick a *fraction* of a second earlier
> than the mind’s ear was now prepared for. The effect was enough, after
> ten minutes, to reduce the thinking processes of even the
> best-prepared to a sort of porridge. The Patrician must have paid the
> clockmaker quite highly.
>
> -- *Feet of Clay*, by Terry Pratchett

### The challenge

Write a function or a program that alternatively outputs "tick" and "tock" every second. There is a 1/5 chance that the tick or tock should be *slightly* faster or *slightly* later than expected, with a 50/50 chance between it being early or late. The time difference should be 0.2 seconds.

The clock should still keep accurate time: that is, if a tick or a tock is early or late, the next tick or tock should still be on-time. The clock itself should not "drift" because of the displaced ticks or tocks.

### Rules

The usual rules and loopholes apply.

This is code golf: shortest code wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Please give an objective definition of "small, but noticeable". I can say 0.01s are noticeable to me because I am [Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_%28Star_Trek%29) (or [Lore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_characters#Lore))

Comment: I think an important part should be that, overall, the program should still keep accurate time

Comment: I agree - I'll rewrite that part so that the clock still keeps accurate time.

Comment: Going Postal - "Sometimes the tick was just a fraction late, sometimes the tock was early. **Occasionally, one or the other didn’t happen at all.**" <- any chance of including the bolded part (emphasis mine)? Also, is there a 1/5 chance of any alteration (fast or slow), or 1/5 chance of fast and another 1/5 of slow?

Comment: @boboquack and if tock is omitted, is the next output a tick or a tock?

Comment: @JayCe I would assume a tick though that's up to the OP of course.

Comment: I would say that if a tock is omitted, the next output would be a tick, and vice versa. Would the Going Postal requirement be a good one for a bonus critera, so -10% for omitting the tick or the tock? Or would it be better as part of the normal requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for feedback on my first question.

Title: Largest Left-Truncatable Prime in Base \$b\$ (A103443)

## Introduction

Numberphile recently posted a video about [truncatable primes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azL5ehbw_24&feature=youtu.be), and the concept seems like it would make a good base for a number of good code golf exercises. I explain the concepts below, but watch the video only if you want ideas about an algorithmic process for finding them.

A left-truncatable prime in base \$b\$ is a prime \$p\$ such that

- all the digits of \$p\$ in base \$b\$ are *nonzero*, and
- when any number of leading digits of \$p\$ when written in base \$b\$ are removed, the result is still a prime. (That is, every suffix of \$p\$ when written in base \$b\$ is a prime, when still interpreted in base \$b\$).

For example, \$1223\$ is a left-truncatable prime in base \$10\$, since \$1223\$, \$223\$, \$23\$, and \$3\$ are all prime; \$1223\$ is also a left-truncatable prime in base \$4\$, since \$1223\$, \$223\$, \$23\$, and \$3\$ are all prime when considered in base \$4\$ (in base \$10\$ they are \$107\$, \$43\$, \$11\$, and \$3\$, respectively). OEIS sequence [A024785](http://oeis.org/A024785) is a list of all left-truncatable primes in base \$10\$.

There are many variants on this concept, but this is all you need for this challenge. This concept also appeared in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89907/right-and-tfel-truncatable-primes) challenge from two years ago.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to find the largest left-truncatable prime in base \$b\$. You can show (from [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1977-31-137/S0025-5718-1977-0427213-2/S0025-5718-1977-0427213-2.pdf) I believe) that there are only finitely many left-truncatable primes for a given base, so the largest one exists. Here it is *instrumental* that we require these primes to have all nonzero digits; otherwise, there would be no largest one.

For example, the largest left-truncatable prime in base \$10\$ is 357686312646216567629137, as mentioned in the above video. These are found in [A103443](https://oeis.org/A103443).

Your program must input an integer \$b \geq 3\$, and output an integer written in base \$10\$ which is the largest left-truncatable prime in base \$b\$ (indeed, one must always exist as well). Your program/function should work for any input \$b\$ your language supports.

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins! No standard loopholes, but built-in primality testing is allowed.

<sub>If your program fails because it would require integers that exceed your language's max integer, then state so in your solution; these solutions are still allowed, but solutions that aren't limited by the language's max integer are better. Alternatively, if you are restricted by a max integer, give the largest left-truncatable prime base \$b\$ that is smaller than this max integer.</sub>

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 10

Output:

> 357686312646216567629137

See [A103443](https://oeis.org/A103443) for more test cases.

*Remember that \$1\$ is not a prime.*

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This looks like a great and well-formatted first challenge, so not much to add. The only thing is that I would add some more test cases to the challenge description itself. I doubt the link https://oeis.org/A103443 will ever be gone, but challenges should be self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: Looks pretty much fine to me as a pure golf. +1 on add a couple more test cases. Note, however, that it is likely that solutions, especially those in golfing languages, may well be posted that do not run for bases above some pretty low limit (e.g. 6) due to the implementation. In cases like this some like the challenge to remain pure-golf and allow this while others choose to require some observed run requirement - e.g. "must've been observed to run for base 12 within 60s (post online interpreter link or local output)". Totally up to you on that (anyone else here have an opinion?).

Comment: I feel like this is going to work sort of like a breadth first search.

Answer (score 1):

#### Locate Substring

This is not a challenge yet, just a place to write down an idea.

Given some finite binary string \$S\$, we can try to find the minimal length \$n \in \mathbb N\$ such that we can uniquely locate each contiguous substring \$ T \$ of \$ S \$ that has length \$ n \$.

#### Example

Let \$ S = 01000110 \$. Then surely \$ n > 1\$. But we also immediately see that \$ n > 2\$ because for instance the substring \$T = 01\$ appears twice in \$ S = \color{red}{01}00\color{red}{01}10\$. But all substrings of length \$ n=3 \$ are distinct, these are in fact (in the order they apppear from left to right) \$ \{ 010, 100, 000, 001, 011, 110 \} \$. This means that \$ n=3 \$ is minimal. [end of example]

Alternatively given some \$ n \$ one might ask to find the longest sequence \$ S \$ such that all substrings \$ T \$ of length \$ n \$ are uniquely locatable.

Comment: Interesting idea, though I think the alternative would create more interesting solutions.

Comment: @OMᗺ I think the solution to the "alternative" are the [de-Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence), which we've covered [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/generate-the-shortest-de-bruijn).

Comment: Ah true, that would be a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

### Order times fully written out in English, alphabetically

A 12h format time of day can be *fully written out in English* according to the following rules:

1. a word from `one` to `twelve`;
2. a space;
3. optionally a word from `one` to `fifty-nine` followed by a space;
4. the "word" `AM` or `PM`.

Examples:

```
 1:31 AM  => "one thirty-one AM"
11:12 PM  => "eleven twelve PM"
 4:00 AM  => "four AM"
```

#### Challenge

The challenge is to take a list of 12h format times and order them alphabetically by the way they are *fully written out in English*.

Input and output format is flexible. Output can either be the times themselves or their *fully written out in English* versions.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest in bytes for each language wins. Standard loopholes forbidden.

#### Test cases

```
[ "1:31 AM", "11:12 PM", "4:00 AM" ]   =>   [ "11:12 PM", "4:00 AM", "1:31 AM" ]
```

More test cases can be added if there is interest.

***I'm mainly concerned this might be a dupe. I couldn't find one.***

Comment: There's no real pattern there, so it will most likely be answers `sortBy(inputs, key=toEnglishString)`, I think. Why not just ask for translating it to English?

Comment: A dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71203/80010 I believe

Answer (score 1):

## Edit distance for sparse strings

The input to this challenge will be two strings of length one million each.  Each string contains only zeros and ones. However each string will contain at most 100 ones and so will be represented by a sorted list of integers. The integers will indicate where the ones are.

**Example of input**

```
[ 42394, 108181, 154190, 217161, 301607, 379951, 412651, 623862, 624712, 783863]
[ 42393, 108181, 154189, 267161, 301608, 379951, 412651, 623862, 624713, 783863]
```

We want to compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between these two strings. However, the standard algorithm will take around 10^12 time which is too slow.

**Task**

Your code should take in the two inputs and output the edit distance between the two strings. The only restriction is that your code must be fast enough (and not use too much memory) so that it will complete in less than a minute on a standard desktop PC. In case of doubt, I will test the code on my 8GB AMD processer PC using test inputs that I will create.

**Small test cases**

To test your code here are some small inputs for strings of length 100 with up to 10 ones.

This pair gives edit distance 8.

```
[18, 23, 30, 40, 47, 53, 60, 73, 89, 94]
[21, 23, 39, 48, 53, 59, 60, 89]
```

This pair gives edit distance 8

```
[19, 25, 26, 40, 43, 62, 74, 75, 85, 89]
[10, 26, 27, 28, 44, 70, 74, 75, 76, 86]
```

This pair gives edit distance 7

```
[ 9, 17, 18, 29, 45, 50, 57, 64, 80]
[ 2, 16, 23, 27, 32, 43, 49, 56, 63, 79]
```

This pair gives edit distance 6

```
[ 3,  9, 12, 33, 39, 49, 55, 72, 84, 94]   
[ 3,  9, 29, 40, 41, 72, 84, 94]
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I don't think they are closely related.

Answer (score 1):

### Make a reversible formula

For the purposes of this question:

1. a basic formula \$ y = f(x) \$ takes one of the following forms:

$$ x \\ g(x) + c \\ c + g(x) \\ g(x) - c \\ c - g(x) \\ g(x) c \\ c g(x) \\ \frac {g(x)} c \\ \frac c {g(x)} $$

where \$ g(x) \$ is a basic formula;

2. a reversible formula \$ y = f(x) \$ takes one of the following three forms:

$$ \begin{align} y = x & \implies x = y \\ y = c - g(x) & \implies x = g^{-1}(c - y) \\ y = \frac c {g(x)} & \implies x = g^{-1} \left ( \frac c y \right ) \end{align} $$

where \$ g(x) \$ is a reversible formula whose reverse is \$ g^{-1}(x) \$ according to the above rules and \$ c \$ is a non-negative integer. A simple example of a reversible formula would be the expression \$ y = \frac 1 {1 - x} \$ whose reverse is \$ x = 1 - \frac 1 y \$.

Your challenge is to take a basic formula and express it as a reversible formula. The following transformations are allowed:

$$ \begin{align} \left . \begin{array}r x + c \\ c + x \end{array} \right \} & \implies c - (0 - x) \\ x - c & \implies 0 - (c - x) \\ \left . \begin{array}r x c \\ c x \end{array} \right \} & \implies \frac c {\frac 1 x} \\ \frac x c & \implies \frac 1 {\frac c x} \end {align} $$

(Note that the strict domain of the resulting formula may exclude some values not excluded in the original formula, but the limit of the formula should be equivalent to the original formula.)

Of course we're dealing in string equations so you'll be using `*` and `/` instead. Examples:

```
(x + 1) * 2 => 2 / (1 / (1 - (0 - x)))

x * 2 + 1 => 1 - (0 - 2 / (1 / x))
```

Do not include extraneous parentheses in your result.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: What's the associativity of `-`?

Comment: @user202729 Normal left associativity.

Comment: What are the rules for spaces in expresisons?

Comment: @user202729 You don't need to support spaces. They're just there for legibility.

Comment: @Neil Cool Challenge! Very interesting

Comment: @Rushabh Comments should only be used for improvement/clarification. For other purposes, use different tools, i.e., flags, votes, answers.

Comment: I find this rather hard to understand, perhaps because it fails to distinguish *equations* from *expressions*, calling both *formulae*. I'm not even sure whether part 2 is talking about transformations between equations or about Boolean expressions. It would perhaps be clearer if all equations were removed and expressions were defined using a grammar in BNF.

Answer (score 1):

## Golf me some Golf

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Write a program to play Golf solitaire!
(I'm somewhat surprised that I haven't seen this pun yet.)

### How to play

Golf uses a standard 52 card deck. Play begins with 7 stacks of 5 cards each, one card forming the foundation, and the remaining 16 cards forming the stock. There are two legal moves:

- Move a card from the top of a stack to the foundation (must be one rank higher or lower)
- Draw the top card of the stock and place it on the foundation

The number of cards remaining in the tableau when you run out of moves is your score, with zero being a perfect game.

To make things easier, queens may be played on kings, and aces and kings can be played on each other. Also, while the stock is normally face-down, you will be able to read it all at once.

### Rules

The input to your program will be 7 lists of 5 cards representing the tableau (with the last cards on top) plus 1 list of 17 representing the stock (the last card being the foundation). These lists can be flattened as desired (you can take 1 list of 35 and 1 list of 17, or just 1 list of 52). Cards are represented as numbers 0-12.

Your program should output a list (or string) of numbers 0-7 representing the moves in a game of Golf. The numbers 0-6 represent playing a card from a column to the foundation, and 7 represents drawing a card from the stock. Any illegal moves (including playing from an empty column or stock) will disqualify your program.

Your score is the number of bytes in your program plus 2 bytes per card left on the stock after running through the 18 games in the scoring set. The program with the lowest score wins.

### Test cases

Example output: (coming soon)

Scoring set: (coming soon)

All games in the scoring set are solvable.

---

*Sandbox questions:*

- <s>Is code-golf appropriate for this scoring metric, or would code-challenge be more appropriate?</s>
- <s>Should I do away with the scoring metric, and just require the games to be solved completely?</s>
- Would it be more interesting to include some unsolvable games in the scoring set to make programs handle that case gracefully?

Comment: Honestly, I think [tag:code-challenge] would be more suitable for this. Code golf usually isn't good for things like this. I'd say best solitaire player wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Should I index like this or like that? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

#### Challenge

Let's take a 0-indexed array of length \$l\$. You can index into it with \$i\$, where \$-l\le i<l\$, and the returned element is the element in position \$[i<0]\times l+i\$ (\$[\dots]\$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)).

In some cases, it's shorter to use a negative index instead of a positive one, counting the minus sign and the digits as bytes. For example, if we want the \$102\$th element of an array with \$104\$ elements, indexing with \$101\$ and \$-3\$ will both give the same result. However, if we write the numbers in code, `101` is 3 bytes long, while `-3` is 2 bytes long, so we prefer `-4`. In other cases, using a negative index is counterproductive (for a code golfer). Such an example is the will to obtain the \$4\$th element of a \$10\$-element array. In this case, we can use \$3\$ and \$-7\$, but `-7` is longer than `3`, so we'll choose `3` instead.

Given two inputs \$l\$ and \$i\$, where \$l>0\$ (it doesn't make sense to index into an empty array) and \$0\le i<l\$ (or \$-l\le i<0\$, be consistent), your job is to determine whether positive or negative indexing is better for code golfing purposes. In case both are of the same length, you may return either decision, even inconsistently. The returned value must be one of two distinct and consistent values, defined by the answerer.

Of course, using [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024) isn't fun, so, if you do use any, then, sorry, your answer isn't valid. ;-)

#### Test cases

Here, `1` is used for negative indexing and `0` for positive. I also always prefer using positive indices, but you may prefer otherwise.

```
l     i           (actual index)
----- ----- ----- -----
    1     0     0     0
   10     9     0     9
 1000   999     1    -1
10000  9755     1  -245
  101   100     1    -1
  150   141     1    -9
  150   140     0   140
```

Comment: Could we output True/False values instead?

Comment: @RushabhMehta `True` and `False` are two distinct values; however, outputting "truthy or falsy" but not necessarily consistent values isn't okay. The actual truthiness of the returned value doesn't matter.

Comment: Ugh...there goes my lean solution

Comment: @RushabhMehta Sorry, but I consider truthiness, as defined by consensus, to be a tad bit unclear, since many languages don't have only one feature you can call an "if construct".

Answer (score 1):

## Fuzzy Circles

## Edit

I don't actually like this challenge all that much. Anyone who wants it can have it, else I'll get rid of it.

## Background

For a real number *x*, let ⌊x⌋ be the greatest integer less than or equal to *x*.

## Challenge

Given an input *n*, find the minimum radius of the circle such that all points that satisfy the following equation are on its interior or border.

⌊x⌋^2+⌊y⌋^2 = *n*

**Input**: A real number *n*

**Output**: A real number representing the radius of the smallest circle that contains in its interior or border all points that satisfy ⌊x⌋^2+⌊y⌋^2 = *n*.

**Note**: The precision expected in this challenge is two decimal places, both for the input and output.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

## Test Cases (More to be added):

`25`->`5.70`

Answer (score 1):

**Distinct Dice Sum Algorithm**

From a puzzle on [Brainden](http://brainden.com/forum/index.php/topic/16576-dice-problem/). Paraphrasing,

> What is the best set of 8 sided dice, each identical, such that 3 dice
>   can generate 120 distinct sums? "Best" means the minimum highest sided
>   die configuration.
>
> With 7 sided dice, the best possible sides for each (identical) die is: 1, 2, 8, 51, 60, 79, 83.

For the sake of discussion, use sides=s, and dice=d.

Note1: 120 is the maximum number of distinct sums with s=8, d=3. The formula is:

$$
\frac{(s+d-1!)}{(s-1)!(d)!}
$$

Similarly, for s=7, d=3, the formula gives 84. And brute force shows that a side of at least 83 is required for this easier problem.

Note2: The lowest numbered side is always 1 for an optimal solution to the original question. (See comments.)

My question is, "What's the [fastest algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) to discover the minimum highest sided die for maximum distinct sums?".

Specifically, is there some existing algorithm, or better yet, formula, for the minimum highest sided die? For determining all sides?

While there are obvious choices for languages, I'm not interested in that. I'm interested in the best algorithm possible in general. A sketch of the algorithm with the best (smallest) Big-O score wins.

Complexity of answers should be expressed by [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation, e.g., M(s) = O(???), with d=3. Ties will be broken according to number of dice, i.e., M(s,d) = O(???).

As a puzzle toy to idle time some years ago, I wrote a brute force solver. Unfortunately, for (s=8, d=3), and even knowing an upper limit, my program never completed the search (uptime was an issue).

Comment: To turn this into a challenge, you'll have to pick an objective winning criterion. [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) would work if you want to minimize asymptotic time complexity, but since the complexity will depend on **s** and **d**, you'll have to combine them somehow.

Comment: *Exactly* 120 distinct sums or *at least* 120 distinct sums?

Comment: "it would be preferable to word your challenge more like a challenge and less like a help request." – [quote Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170863/checking-a-file-contains-only-null-bytes#comment412436_170863).

Comment: The challenge can be trivially solved in linear time in the output (which is optimal time), because note that the largest face need to be at least 41 (otherwise `3 ≤ sum ≤ 120` and there can't be 120 values, assuming all values are positive integers), therefore for all `s ≥ 41` just output `1 ... 41` and a bunch of other `1`s to fill up the faces. Not interesting.

Comment: @user202729 I don't think that works.  You have 8 faces to work with, which is less than 41.

Comment: @NathanMerrill No, you have `s` faces to work with. If s<41 just brute force it (O(1)). Otherwise use the algorithm above.

Comment: @user202729 Right, for s>41, it's trivial.  What is not trivial is less than 41, which I don't see the algorithm for.  Which algorithm are you talking about?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Note that the challenge requires smallest asymptotic complexity, not runtime. All (correct) algorithm which only operates on bounded input works in O(1), by the definition of "asymptotic".

Comment: @user202729 True, but it is trivial to increase `120` as well, to provide a way for measuring the asymptotic nature of the algorithm.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Then the challenge needs to be edited to explicitly specify that.

Comment: @user202729 perhaps, but I could see an argument that the 120 is useful to provide a solid ground for the algorithm, as long as they indicate that it is arbitrary.

Comment: 120: For s=8, d=3, 120 is the maximum number of distinct sums. I believe the formula is M=((s-1)+d)!/((s-1)!d!). Not sure how to write that well in a comment, but sCd with repetitions.

Comment: Big-Oh notation does not assume a fixed input. If the input is fixed, any algorithm can be said to be O(1), which is unhelpful. For example, f(a) = O(a^2). It's often harder to describe this with more than one variable, but it might be f(a,b) = O(max(a,b)^2).

Comment: @QuantumMechanic for scoring the algorithms, I think you could assume a constant `d`, but as a tie-breaker, include `d`.

Comment: I think there's an implicit assumption that the smallest permitted value on the side of a die is 1, but that should be made explicit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, I think you're right, the solution will have a side with 1. Thinking it through, if you add 1 to each of `1, 2, 8, 51, 60, 79, 83`, each sum would increase by 3. Since they are all distinct before, adding 3 to each one, they would all still be distinct. But the highest numbered side would be 84. QED? I'll add that to the OP. It really should change anything, but maybe it will spur someone on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Permutation Encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171605/75951)

*Now posted to the main site. Check the revisions log if you want to see the WIP versions.*

Comment: IMO it would improve the question to edit in the part about Discord so that it is a motivated problem rather than an arbitrary challenge. All of the elements of this have already been covered by earlier challenges (bijective bases and permutation indices), but the variation in lengths probably push it out of duplicate territory.

Comment: I put the backstory at the bottom. I thought it had lower priority than the problem itself. I'm also concerned that if I put it at the top, it'd give the impression that Discord reactions is the problem rather than the actual problem I posted. Even if it's clear they're distinct, it might still be confusing since the actual problem is very different from its inspiration. // Also, there's some room for creativity here, I used a numbering approach but I'm sure more clever encoding methods are possible and golf better. There's 2.16E148 possible original and 2.81E148 possible encoded strings.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted "Extras" as heading some information which you intended to be only for the sandbox.

Comment: If you've posted this to main, could you please clear and delete it to clear up clutter? Thanks!

Comment: Please delete your challenge proposal to remove clutter.

Answer (score 1):

## Compile Brainbash to BF

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Background

[BF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BF) is an esolang known for it's terseness and small character set. The language operates on a tape of unsigned 8-bit integers, and with a pointer to modify certain values. This pointer starts at the first cell. BF has the following commands available to program with:

```
+       increment the current cell
-       decrement the current cell
>       move the pointer to the next cell on the right
<       move the pointer to the next cell on the left
.       output the current cell as a character
,       take a character of input
[       begin a loop while the current cell is not zero
]       end that loop
```

[Brainbash](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brainbash) is a language similar to BF, but it has two tapes. To deal with this, Brainbash has a "tape focus"; one tape at a time is being worked on. Each tape also has its own pointer. Thus, Brainbash has a few more commands in addition to BF's:

```
~       swap the tape focus
*       swap tapes and copy the pointer from the previous tape to the next one
{       if the current cell is not zero, execute the code until the next `}` that matches 
}       marks the end an if statement
```

(There are more commands, but they are not being considered for the purposes of this challenge.)

### Challenge

Given a non-empty Brainbash program `P`, translate that program to BF. That is, output a program `Q` whose I/O behavior is identical to that of `P`.

This is a code-golf, so the shortest in program (in bytes) that successfully does this wins.

### Specific rules

- You may assume that each tape is infinite to the right starting at the origin.
- You may assume that the input is a valid program which has matching `{` and `}` and `[` and `]`.

### Example Test Cases

(to be introduced)

Comment: Do the Brainbash tapes wrap, or are they infinite in each direction? Are the Brainfuck commands also Brainbash commands?

Comment: What does it mean to translate? Only keep I/O behaviour the same or also some tape structure?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork (1) You must support at least 30000 cells to the right of the origin for both tapes (2) Yes

Comment: @JonathanFrech Keep I/O behaviour

Answer (score 1):

## Make it rotationally-symmetric

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(sandbox note: am I using the wrong terminology?)

#### Background

While looking at [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172005/a-chiral-puzzle), I notice <s>many</s> some of the answers has 4-fold rotational symmetry. I think it would be convenient to have a program to automatically do it.

#### Challenge

- Take input as a string, for which when separated by newlines, all line has equal length. (i.e., the input is rectangular)
- The output is the smallest square with 4-fold rotational symmetry, where the top-left corner is equal to the rectangle.

#### Sample input/output

```
Input:
aba
bab
aba

Output:
aba
bab
aba

Input:
 begin write('left')end.// 
/e .dne)'thgir'(etirw nigeb

Output:
 begin write('left')end.// 
/e .dne)'thgir'(etirw nigeb
/g                        e
.i                       .g
dn                       di
n                        nn
ew                       e 
)r                       )w
'i                       'r
tt                       ti
fe                       ht
e(                       ge
l'                       i(
'r                       r'
(i                       'l
eg                       (e
th                       ef
it                       tt
r'                       i'
w)                       r)
 e                       we
nn                        n
id                       nd
g.                       i.
e                        g/
begin write('right')end. e/
 //.dne)'tfel'(etirw nigeb 

Input:
abc
cde

Output:
abcca
cdedb
ce ec
bdedc
accba
```

#### Winning criteria

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: Could input be a list of strings?

Comment: Do the filler characters have to be spaces?

Comment: Suggested test case: 'ab\naa'

Answer (score 1):

## Mini Castle Wars [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

**Note**: This is very early draft, and I'll try to develop when I get some time to spare.

---

Inspired by [a previous KOTH based on a card game (but not actually a card game)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171810/78410).

### Background

This challenge involves a simplified version of the card game [Castle Wars](http://www.kongregate.com/games/m0rkeulv/castlewars).

### Game rules

#### Gameplay

Just like many other card games, Castle Wars is a two-player turn-based game.

Each player starts with 30 units of **castle**, 5 units of **fence**, no **shield**, 2 **workers**, 8 **bricks**, 2 **magicians**, and 8 **crystals**. Each player is dealt (TBD, 5?) cards from his own deck at start.

Each resource has the following function:

- **Castle**: Directly related to the **winning condition** (see below).
- **Fence**: Fences can block the opponent's attack. If the attack would damage the castle by N units, the fence is damaged N units instead. If the fence is less than N units, it becomes zero and the remaining damage is dealt to the castle.
- **Shield**: If a castle is shielded, it can nullify any amount of damage to the castle AND the fence, exactly once. Shield can't be stacked.
- **Workers**: Each worker produces **one brick every turn**.
- **Magicians**: Each magician produces **one crystal every turn**.
- **Bricks** and **Crystals**: Every card spends some of these resources to take effect.

Each turn works as follows:

1. He gets the resources produced by his own workers and magicians.
2. The player draws a card from his own deck.
3. He plays a card. If he has enough resources, the card takes effect immediately (including the resources spent). Otherwise, it has no effect whatsoever.
4. The played card returns to the deck, and the deck is shuffled.

<s>In order to compensate the first-player advantage, resource generation is skipped at the first turn of the game.</s> (TBD)

#### Cards & deck

A deck consists of at least (TBD) cards, and may include at most (TBD) copies of the same card.

Here is the full list of cards.

- (TBD, will reflect the actual cards in the game)

#### Winning condition

A player wins if the opponent's castle is destroyed (0 units or below), or his own castle grows to 100 units or higher. If 100 turns are passed without a player winning, the one with higher castle is declared the winner. Same castle height after 100 turns is a draw.

### Tournament

Every bot will have (TBD, even number) matches with every other bot, alternating the first turn.

### Controller

TBD. This will ideally be implemented in [KOTH-Webplayer](https://github.com/davidje13/koth-webplayer).

### Submission guide

A submission will look like this:

**Deck**

```
'AAAAABBBBBCCDDEXYZ'
```

**Bot**

```
return hand[Math.random()*hand.length|0];
```

The **Deck** is a string literal that describes the list of cards your bot will use. The **Bot** is a snippet that will fit into the following function's body:

```
function play(hand, myResources, opResources, opPlayed, storage) {
    // function body here
}
```

The description of parameters:

- `hand` is an Array of (TBD) cards in your bot's hand. Your bot's job is to choose a card to play.
- `myResources` and `opResources` are two Objects that have the information of all the resources (the bot's and the opponent's, respectively). Available keys are `castle`, `fence`, `worker`, `brick`, `magician`, `crystal`, `shield`. (`shield` is a Boolean indicating whether the player's castle is shielded or not; others are simple numbers.)
- `opPlayed` is the card played at the opponent's last turn.
- `storage` is an Object you can freely use to store information between turns. It is initially empty (`{}`).

---

#### Meta

- I originally planned to have a simplified version of the original Castle Wars, but on second thought, the rules are not *that* complicated and removing some resource types may break the balance of the game (as some interesting cards have to be revised). **Would it be good to implement the full game instead?**

Comment: Fantastic to see this brewing in the sandbox! Here are a couple pieces of criticism and some potential solutions: a) No tournament type is specified - I'm assuming it's round-robin. This should be added to the spec. a) Is there a need to compensate for the first-player advantage? Surely, a two-way round-robin would be fair enough, no? I'm not sure how large the first-player advantage is, though, so I could be wrong here. c) I've found that there's a handy way to handle persistent storage of things in JavaScript - [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: cont. c) I would recommend that all future JS KOTHs required a function factory pattern from players. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/alion02/d8f89857d82d0f9e7d68df8d808fad63) an example of how that can be useful for entries. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/alion02/6fa2c6b461895353a4c570d5d4ee8a2f) how that looks without the closure pattern, and how it negatively affects entries.

Comment: cont. c) For this challenge, this could be additionally useful, since you require players to choose a deck for themselves. The bots could return a `{deck, func}` object during setup that way.

Answer (score 1):

## Prettify Pixiedust

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

So [Pixiedust](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374624/6388243) is a new esolang I've created. One of the primary points is that it should *look like pixie dust*—exactly the things that your programs should fix.

## Input

The input will be a program written in Pixiedust. Since this is **not** a challenge to parse the language, it won't be in raw code, but a list of numbers and the strings separating them. The numbers can be taken as the number itself, or their representation in the program.

## Randomizing the Literals

For each numeric literal, there are many ways to represent them:

- Randomly pad the beginning with `.` characters. It should be an even distribution between padding it to 32 bits and padding it to the base length.
- If the number is at the end of the line, then take an even split between including and excluding the terminating `*`.

## Scattering

At this point, you should have the lines calculated—let's call this the *half-pretty program*. For each line of output:

- Start with a line of pure spaces 4 times the length of the longest half-pretty line.
- Randomly select spaces from it to replace with program characters. Every combination of spaces should have an equal chance.
- Replace those spaces with the corresponding characters, without changing the order that they appear in.
- (Optional) trim off trailing spaces.

## Scoring

The winner will be the shortest answer in bytes. Additionally, there will be a 50-rep bounty for the first answer written in Pixiedust.

---

Examples will be coming once I finish the interpreter and make some submissions to other challenges in Pixiedust.

Comment: `Since this is not a challenge to parse the language,` I mean, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

## Iteration Hierarchy

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)

This is based on the [m(n) map](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/M(n)_map). m<sub>k</sub> takes in k functions and one natural input n, and iterates the first function n times onto the next argument, and then fills in the rest of the arguments.

\$m_1=f_0\mapsto n\mapsto f_0^n(n)\$

\$m_2=f_1\mapsto f_0\mapsto n\mapsto f_1^n(f_0)(n)\$

\$m_3=f_2\mapsto f_1\mapsto f_0\mapsto n\mapsto f_2^n(f_1)(f_0)(n)\$

etc. where \$f^n(x)=f(f(f(\dots f(x)\dots)))\$ with \$n\$ calls to \$f\$ (a.k.a. [function iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition)).

Note particularly that \$m_2(f_1)(f_0)(2)=f_1(f_1(f_0))(2)\ne f_1(f_1(f_0(2)))\$ *i.e. it iterates the first argument over the second argument* and then applies the remaining arguments afterwards.

---

#### Examples:

Let \$s(n)=n+1\$.

**m<sub>1</sub>(s)(5)**

```
m₁(s)(5)
= s(s(s(s(s(5)))))                                x5 iterations of s
= 10
```

**m<sub>1</sub>(m<sub>1</sub>(s))(4)**

```
m₁(m₁(s))(4)
= m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(4))))                   x4 iterations of m₁(s)
= m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(s(s(s(s(4)))))))              x4 iterations of s
= m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(8)))
= m₁(s)(m₁(s)(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(8))))))))))         x8 iterations of s
= m₁(s)(m₁(s)(16))
= ...
= m₁(s)(32)
= ...
= 64
```

**m<sub>2</sub>(m<sub>1</sub>)(s)(3)**

```
m₂(m₁)(s)(3)
= m₁(m₁(m₁(s)))(3)                                x3 iterations of m₁
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(3)))              x3 iterations of m₁(m₁(s))
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(3)))))    x3 iterations of m₁(s)
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(s(s(s(3)))))))  x3 iterations of s
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(6))))
= ...
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(m₁(s))(24))
= m₁(m₁(s))(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(24)))))))))))))))))))))))))
= ...
= m₁(m₁(s))(402653184)
= ...
= ???
```

**m<sub>3</sub>(m<sub>2</sub>)(m<sub>1</sub>)(s)(2)**

```
m₃(m₂)(m₁)(s)(2)
= m₂(m₂(m₁))(s)(2)                                x2 iterations of m₂
= m₂(m₁)(m₂(m₁)(s))(2)                            x2 iterations of m₂(m₁)
= m₁(m₁(m₂(m₁)(s)))(2)                            x2 iterations of m₁
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(2))                 x2 iterations of m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(m₂(m₁)(s)(2)))          x2 iterations of m₂(m₁)(s)
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(m₁(m₁(s))(2)))          x2 iterations of m₁
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(m₁(s)(m₁(s)(2))))       x2 iterations of m₁(s)
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(m₁(s)(s(s(2)))))        x2 iterations of s
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(m₁(s)(4)))
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₂(m₁)(s)(8))
= m₁(m₂(m₁)(s))(m₁(m₁(m₁(m₁(m₁(m₁(m₁(m₁(s))))))))(8))
= ...
= ???
```

#### Aside:

This hierarchy is closely related to the [fast-growing hiearchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Functions_in_fast-growing_hierarchies) when using a base function of s.

In fact, the last example is already much larger than Graham's number, and \$m_n(m_{n-1})\dots(m_1)(s)(n)\approx f_{\varepsilon_0}(n)\$ in the fast-growing hierarchy.

#### Code Golf Challenge:

> Write the shortest possible function subprogram for \$m_k\$. Code size is measured in bytes.

Here's an example program (Ruby, I can golf this down to about 140 bytes):

```
iterate=->f,n{->g{
    i=g
    n.times{i=f[i]}
    i}}

m=->k{
    x="->n{y=iterate[f#{k-1},n]; (0...#{k-1}).map{|l| y=eval(\"y[f\#{l}]\")}; y[n]}"
    (0...k).map{|l| x="->f#{l}{"+x+"}"}
    eval(x)}
```

**NB**: As noted above, the growth rate of \$m_n(m_{n-1})\dots(m_1)(s)(n)\$ is comparable to \$f_{\varepsilon_0}(n)\$. *If this can be golfed far enough below 100 bytes, it could well place in the top 5 of the [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028) question.*

Comment: BTW, [we have support for MathJax on PPCG now](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16556/67312), using `\$` as delimiters -- unless you really like using `<sub>` tags...

Comment: Ah thanks lol. \o/

Answer (score 1):

Challenge

### Max Sum String

Given an input string, return the max word based on the sum of each word's unicode characters.

## Rules

- The input should be seperated by whitespace
- The value of each word is based on the sum of each character in the word's UTF-16 code
- The output should be the word

## Examples

```
Input: "a b c d e"
Output: "e"

Input: "this is a test"
Output: "test"

Input: "test Test"
Output: "test"

Input: "hello world"
Output: "world"

Input: "    ️  "
Output: "️"
```

I doubt it's optimal at all, but here's the code I came up with to accomplish this challenge:

```
let str = "hello world";
Object.keys(str.split(' ').map(w => {return {[w]: [...w].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}}).reduce((a, b) => { return Object.values(a)[0] > Object.values(b)[0] ? a : b}))[0];
```

Comment: Will all words be unique, or can there be duplicated words? For example, is `"testing testing this is a test"` a valid input? I would advice to keep all words unique, but it's your choice. If duplicated words are possible, would this test case result in `"testing"`, `["testing", "testing"]`, or either is allowed?

Comment: Also, even if duplicated words aren't allowed, what if the sum of two words have equal values, and are the max? Do we output either of the possible words, both of them, or either of these options is allowed? (I would suggest allowing both, and add a test case like that. For example `"àà as a test"` resulting in `["àà", "test"]`.) Other than that it's a nice challenge, so +1 from me. Already prepared an 8-bytes solution for it. :)

Comment: I thought it should print out the first word, that's an easy fix to my js code. Thank you for the feedback, I'll post it soon!

Answer (score 1):

## [Be there, for the square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173635/be-there-for-the-square)

Comment: Same idea, but extended to a cube: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92410/56433

Comment: Good catch! I think that the cube challenge is different enough that the answers won't just be taken from there. My challenge skips a lot of the special cases, which could make for some optimization.

Answer (score 1):

## Ascii Table to UTF-8

When I write documentation, comments, etc. I love making ASCII tables. They usually end up looking pretty good, but I always feel that they could look even better - especially since UTF-8/Unicode includes the [box drawing characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/box-drawing/). However, these characters are very burdensome to use, requiring several key presses to insert. Your task? Write a program or a function that can automatically convert ASCII tables to the UTF-8/Unicode equivalent.

### Challenge

Write a program, that given an ASCII table as an input string, outputs the table redrawn with the Unicode/UTF-8 box drawing characters. Specifically, the characters that are a part of the table should be translated as follows:

```
(Unicode)
- to ─ (\u2500)
| to │ (\u2502)
= to ═ (\u2550)

and + to one of:
   ┌ (\u250C), ┐ (\u2510), └ (\u2514), ┘ (\u2518),
   ├ (\u251C), ┤ (\u2524), ┬ (\u252C), ┴ (\u2534),
   ┼ (\u253C)
or, if '=' on either side:
   ╒ (\u2552), ╕ (\u2555), ╘ (\u2558), ╛ (\u255D),
   ╞ (\u255E), ╡ (\u2561), ╤ (\u2564), ╧ (\u2567),
   ╪ (\u256A)
```

### Details

**I/O:**

- [Default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447) is allowed
- You may take a path to a file instead of the table as a string.
- You may output to a file and take the file name as an additional argument.

  - However, you **may not modify the *input* file**. (It should be retained for ease of future editing)

**Input:**

- You may assume that every row of input has been padded to be the same length with .
- You may not assume that the first character after a newline is a part of the table borders (as it may be whitespace).
- Input is considered a valid table if all characters (that are a part of the table) `-=|` are connected to exactly two characters and `+` are connected to at least one character both horizontally and vertically.
- Your program may not produce any errors with valid inputs.
- If the input is not valid the behavior is undefined and you may produce any output.

**Output:**

- Any of the characters `-=|+` that are not a part of the table **must** be left as-is.
- Similarly, any other characters must be left as-is.
- A single leading and/or trailing newline is allowed.

**Other:**

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, as per usual.
- If your preferred language has a built-in that solves this problem, you may not use it.

  - This means programs, functions, subroutines or instructions that would be valid submissions for this challenge with no additions.

**Connected characters**:

A character is connected to another, if:

- It is `|` and is directly above or below `+` or `|`;
- It is `-` and is directly before or after `+` or `-`;
- It is `=` and is directly before or after `+` or `=`;
- It is `+` and is directly above or below `|` or `+`, or is directly before or after `-`, `=` or `+`.

A character is considered a part of the table, if it is connected to any character that is a part of the table. By definition, the first `+` in the input is a part of the table.

### Examples

Examples available [here](https://pastebin.com/Wzcr113K) as a copy-pastable version.

```
 Input:                    Output:
+------------------+      ┌──────────────────┐
|   Hello+World!   |      │   Hello+World!   │
+==================+      ╞══════════════════╡
| This is+my first |  ->  │ This is+my first │
|+-+ code|golf  +-+|      │+-+ code|golf  +-+│
|+-+chall|enge! +-+|      │+-+chall|enge! +-+│
+------------------+      └──────────────────┘

     +===+===+===+             ╒═══╤═══╤═══╕
     | 1 | 2 | 3 |             │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
 +---+===+===+===+         ┌───╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |         │ 1 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
 +---+---+---+---+    ->   ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 6 |         │ 2 │ 2 │ 4 │ 6 │
 +---+---+---+---+         ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
 |-3 |-3 |-6 |-9 |         │-3 │-3 │-6 │-9 │
 +===+---+---+---+         ╘═══╧───┴───┴───┘

      +-----+         ->      <Undefined>

      +-----+         ->      ┌─────┐
      +-----+                 └─────┘

+-----------------+
|  Hello, World!  |
| This is invalid |   ->      <Undefined>
|      input      |
 -----------------+

       ++++                      ┌┬┬┐
       ++++           ->         ├┼┼┤
       ++++                      └┴┴┘

       +--+
       ++++           ->      <Undefined>
       +--+
```

### Finally...

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the least amount of bytes wins. Happy golfing!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Comment: This is a solid first challenge, nice job.  The test cases are good as well. 1. What should happen on the input `+` (all by itself?), or the input `+---+`?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Good question. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

## Converting a number from Zeckendorf Representation to Decimal

[moved to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173601/converting-a-number-from-zeckendorf-representation-to-decimal)

Comment: Questions should try to be self-contained so that people don't have to go off-site, and so links don't end up being dead.

Answer (score 1):

[**One line keyboard**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173776/one-line-keyboard)

Comment: Some questions: What happened to the tab key? Why are there no upper-cased letters in the alternate section? I think it would be a bit more clear if you'd wrap the actual characters in `\``. OT: This challenge remind me a bit of [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1241676) :)

Comment: Another thing: I can't think of a language/algorithm rn, but someone might struggle with the empty string and it doesn't really add much to the core of the challenge. You might want to loosen that requirement to only allow non-empty inputs, but it's your call and either way is fine.

Comment: @BMO I've excluded the tab key as it will never appear in the input (not in ascii range 32-126) and as far as I'm aware it can't be used to input other special characters. I didn't include the upper cased letters in the alternate section as they're always the same key as their lowercase counterpart (although am happy to edit if it makes it clearer). Finally, I wanted to wrap the characters in a backtick but was unsure how to escape it in the first line :)

Comment: Ah forgot about the printable range, makes sense. It wouldn't hurt to add them and would make it more complete, but it is not really essential to the challenge. I think using `<code>...</code>` is the easiest way or you can use double backticks.

Comment: Why does `{}` matters, as you can't access Shift key on that line anyway?

Comment: @user202729 Originally I just typed out all the keys to leave it up to each person to work out what they could use, but thinking about it that seems unecessary so I'll change it to just characters

Comment: please delete this now that this has been posted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Idolize Me! - JS idol simulation KotH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[simulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)

### Introduction

There are quite a lot of ACG titles featuring idols in Japan. Inspired by different kinds of such games, I decided to make up my idol simulation game.

### What is "Idolize Me!™"?

Idolize Me!™ (tentative) is based on an idol training facility featuring a monthly tournament, in which all idols compete for fame. Every idol has the following 4 kinds of attributes (or abilities):

- **E**loquence (How well you speak)
- **S**inging (How well you sing)
- **D**ance (How well you dance)
- **P**erformance (How well you act)

Also, every idol has the corresponding improvisation level (affects on-stage performance) and specialized skills. There are training courses to upgrade these abilities and skills, and idols can also "learn" from rivals during monthly tournaments to gain abilities and improvisation.

The tournament is a Swiss-system tournament, idols gain and lose fame during 1-on-1 performance battles, and gain fame according to their overall tournament results.
Each battle consists of 3 rounds, selected from the 4 types of performances with different focusing attributes:

- Stand-up comedy battle (Eloquence)
- Duet battle (Singing)
- Dance battle (Dance)
- Drama battle (Performance)

Each idol can choose to ban one type he/she does not want to participate, and can choose to specify one type he/she want to participate. Other rounds will be selected randomly, and after 3 rounds, the idol who wins more rounds wins the battle. It is possible to end up with a draw, but this is very rare.

Every one starts with the same amount of fame. After 3 years of training and competitions, the most famous idol will become the Super Idol!

### Algorithmic Explanation

- Each idol starts with 2500 units of fame, 10000 units of ability to be allotted to the 4 attributes by yourself, and 20 units of improvisation and 10 units of skill per attribute.
- The main loop consists of the following components, and will be run for 36 rounds (=3 years):

  - **Training** (4 rounds per round): Each idol will be given 100 units of ability and 5 units of improvisation. You can allot however you wish, **but beware that improvisation caps at 50 units per attribute.** After allotment you can learn some skills or to strengthen your abilities at the cost of losing some improvisation. Every unit of improvisation can be converted to 5 units of ability or 0.2 units of skill. **Beware that skill also caps at 50 units per attribute.**
  - **Tournament**: After 4 rounds of training there will be the tournament. The tournament will be a Swiss-system tournament, and consist of \$\lceil log_2(n+1) \rceil\$ rounds, where \$n\$ is the number of idols. Each round will be run in the following manner:

    1. Group the idols into a group of 2 according to their running rankings.
    2. For each group, each idol chooses one attribute from the 4 attributes, and discloses its corresponding ability.
    3. Then, being told the attributes and abilities, each idol decides one attribute to ban. Giving up the chance to ban is allowed.
    4. Next, being told the choice of ban, each idols decides one round to battle. They can still choose the banned choice, **but the choice will be replaced by random rounds.**
    5. Fill the remaining rounds with random rounds not being banned until there are 3 rounds.
    6. In each round, each idol can choose whether to use skill of the attribute of the round. There is only one chance of using skills per idol per a 3-round battle. Then the final score of each idol will be calculated with the following formula:

$$
score=\sum_{attr}{\Biggl\lfloor ability_{attr}\times multiplier_{type,attr}\times\left[0.7+r\times \left(0.3+\frac{improvisation_{attr}}{100}\right)\right]\times\left(1+\frac{skill_{attr}}{100}\right)\Biggr\rfloor}
$$

Where \$ability_{attr}\$ is your ability, \$improvisation_{attr}\$ is your improvisation, \$skill_{attr}\$ is your skill, all of the attribute \$attr\$, and \$r\$ is a random number in the range\$[0, 1)\$, with a slightly larger probability near \$1\$. The value of \$multiplier_{type,attr}\$ is in the table below:

```
      type   | Stand-up comedy     Duet Battle  Dance Battle  Drama Battle
attr         | Battle (Eloquence)  (Singing)    (Dance)       (Performance)
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
Eloquence    | 1.5                 0.8          0.5           1.2
Singing      | 0.8                 1.5          1.2           0.5
Dance        | 0.5                 1.2          1.5           0.8
Performance  | 1.2                 0.5          0.8           1.5
```

- (contd)

  - (contd)

    7. The idol with higher score wins the round, and idol who wins more rounds wins the battle.
    8. Winner of the battle will be award 2 points, loser 0 points, and in the case of a draw, 1 point each.
    9. Winner gets extra 10 units of ability and 1 unit of improvisation. **For each losing round, the defeated idol gets 20 units of ability and 2 unit of improvisation, and for each draw round, each idol gets 30 units of ability and 3 unit of improvisation**, to be allotted at the same time (**Beware again that improvisation caps at 50 units per attribute.**) -- This is the core of so-called "learning from rivals".
    10. The delta fame is calculated as \$\lfloor10\times diff\times\frac{fame_{loser}}{fame_{winner}}\rfloor\$, where \$diff\$ is the difference of winning rounds in the battle. Winner gets this amount and loser loses this amount of fame.
    11. If the number of idols is odd, the idol who ranked the last will be consider a 0-battle win automatically, so fame, ability and improvisation are not affected.
    12. Sort the idols according to the following order, with the one at the top having the highest priority, all in descending order:

        1. Tournament points (TP)
        2. Number of battles won
        3. Battle difference (BD) (Number of rounds won - Number of rounds lost)
        4. Number of rounds won (BF)
        5. Score difference (PD) (Total score got - Total score lost)
        6. Total score got (PF)
        7. Drawing lots
  - After all rounds, fame will be awarded by the following formula:

$$
increase_{fame_{idol}}=\Biggl\lfloor\left[\left(\frac{n - rank + 1}{n}\right)^{1.5}\times 80+20\right]\times\frac{fame_{average}}{fame_{idol}}\Biggr\rfloor
$$

Where \$n\$ is the number of idols.

### Submission requirements:

Your bot must be a JS function with a name, **prefably a human name (because the idol theme)**, distinct from other bots, that accepts an integer argument `id` (you must not change this argument name) and returns an object with 2 fields and 8 functions. The 2 fields are `id` and `name` (**please don't change the `id,` line in the template**). The 8 function are as follows:

1. `allot(type, amount)`: Allotment of `amount` units of `type`.

   - Arguments:

     - `type`: one of `"ability"` or `"improvisation"`, the type to be allotted
     - `amount`: an integer, the amount to be allotted
   - Return values:

     - An object with 4 numbers named `E`, `S`, `D` and `P`, denoting your decision of the allotment of the 4 attributes. The 4 numbers must sum up to `amount`, otherwise your decision will be voided.
2. `review(ranking, battles)`: Your bot can review the battle results and adjust your plans.

   - Arguments:

     - `ranking`: an array of objects of the following entries, in ascending order of the bots' ranking, the running ranking during the tournament:

       - `id`: an integer, the ID of the bot
       - `W`: an integer, battle wins
       - `D`: an integer, battle draws
       - `L`: an integer, battle losses
       - `BF`: an integer, rounds won
       - `BA`: an integer, rounds lost
       - `BD`: an integer, BF - BA
       - `PF`: an integer, total score won by the bot
       - `PA`: an integer, total score won by opponent
       - `PD`: an integer, PF - PA
       - `pts`: an integer, tournament points
     - `battles`: an array of objects of the following entries, the details of all battles:

       - `aID`: an integer, the ID of idol A
       - `aWin`: an integer, rounds idol A won
       - `aPtTotal`: an integer, total score idol A got
       - `bID`: an integer, the ID of idol B. `-1` stands for no opponent
       - `bWin`: an integer, rounds idol B won
       - `bPtTotal`: an integer, total score idol B got
       - `result`: an array of the following entries, the details of the sub-rounds of the battle:

         - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute of the round
         - `aTotal`: an integer, the score of idol A
         - `bTotal`: an integer, the score of idol B
   - Return values:

     - None.
3. `learn()`: Your bot can learn one type of skill at the cost of the improvisation of that attribute.

   - Arguments:

     - None.
   - Return values:

     - `null`, or an object of the following entries, the decision:

       - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the skill you want to learn
       - `unit`: a positive number, the amount you want to learn. You cannot learn more than your improvisation of that attribute allows.
4. `convert()`: Your bot can strengthen one type of ability at the cost of the improvisation of that attribute.

   - Arguments:

     - None.
   - Return values:

     - `null`, or an object of the following entries, the decision:

       - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the ability you want to strengthen
       - `unit`: a positive number, the amount you want to strengthen. You cannot strengthen more than your improvisation of that attribute allows.
5. `disclose(rival)`: Disclose your attribute during battle.

   - Arguments:

     - `rival`: an integer, rival's ID
   - Return values:

     - one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute you want to disclose
6. `forbid(rival, attribute, value)`: Bans an attribute during battle.

   - Arguments:

     - `rival`: an integer, rival's ID
     - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute rival discloses
     - `value`: an integer, the ability of that attribute rival discloses
   - Return values:

     - one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute you want to ban
7. `choose(attribute, value, forbidden)`: Chooses an attribute during battle.

   - Arguments:

     - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute rival discloses
     - `value`: an integer, the ability of that attribute rival discloses
     - `forbidden`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute rival bans
   - Return values:

     - one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the round you want to choose
8. `skill(attribute)`: Decides whether to use skill.

   - Arguments:

     - `attribute`: one of `"E"`, `"S"`, `"D"` or `"P"`, the attribute of the round
   - Return values:

     - `true` or `false`, the decision whether to use skill of the attribute of the round.

[image]

Here is a template to use:

```javascript
function YourIdolBot(id) {
    // Your local storage
    
    return {
        id, // Don't change this line
        name: "", // Your bot's name
        allot(type, amount) {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return {
                E: 0,
                S: 0,
                D: 0,
                P: 0
            };
        },
        review(ranking, battles) {
            // Your logic
            
        },
        learn() {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return {
                attribute: "",
                unit: 0
            };
        },
        convert() {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return {
                attribute: "",
                unit: 0
            };
        },
        disclose(rival) {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return "";
        },
        forbid(rival, attribute, value) {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return "";
        },
        choose(attribute, value, forbidden) {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return "";
        },
        skill(attribute) {
            // Your logic
            
            // Your return value
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Your submissions must not:

- Corrupt the simulation;
- Return values beyond requirements;
- Call `IdolizeMeAPI.query()` with other bot's ID (see below);
- Affect other bots' code;
- Fetch external sources;
- Define and use new global variables;
- Has expletive inside the code (Beware of idols' image)

Violations will render the bot invalid and thus be disqualified and excluded from the simulation.

### API

Idolize Me! provides an API that lets your idol bot query the current stats of its own. By calling `IdolizeMeAPI.query(id)` with your bot's ID. **YOU MUST NOT CALL `IdolizeMeAPI.query()` WITH OTHER BOT'S ID. THIS WILL LEAD TO DISQUALIFICATION.** This method returns an object with the following entries, which is the details of your bot:

- `id`: an integer, your bot's id
- `name`: a string, your bot's name
- `ability`: an object with 4 numbers named `E`, `S`, `D` and `P`, your bot's ability of each attribute
- `improvisation`: an object with 4 numbers named `E`, `S`, `D` and `P`, your bot's improvisation of each attribute
- `skill`: an object with 4 numbers named `E`, `S`, `D` and `P`, your bot's skill of each attribute
- `fame`: a number, your bot's fame

### Test Area

Here is a snippet that allows test on the bots:

```js
function log(msg) {
  $("#log").html($("#log").html() + msg + "\n\n");
}

function cls() {
  $("#log").html("");
}

function startIdolizeMeAPI(bots, seed, loopRounds, logBattles) {
 const ALLOT_LIMIT = {
  ability: Infinity,
  improvisation: 50,
  skill: 50
 };
 const MULTIPLIER = {
  E: {E: 1.5, S: 0.8, D: 0.5, P: 1.2},
  S: {E: 0.8, S: 1.5, D: 1.2, P: 0.5},
  D: {E: 0.5, S: 1.2, D: 1.5, P: 0.8},
  P: {E: 1.2, S: 0.5, D: 0.8, P: 1.5}
 };

 function checkAllot(idol, type, amount, add) {
  var values = idol.idol.allot(type, amount);
  var total = 0;
  for (var i of "ESDP")
   total += values[i];
  if (Math.abs(total - amount) < 1e-10) {
   if (add) {
    for (var i of "ESDP") {
     idol[type][i] += values[i];
     if (idol[type][i] > ALLOT_LIMIT[type])
      idol[type][i] = ALLOT_LIMIT[type];
    }
   }
   else {
    for (var i of "ESDP") {
     if (values[i] > ALLOT_LIMIT[type])
      values[i] = ALLOT_LIMIT[type];
    }
    return values;
   }
  }
  else if (!add)
   return {E: 0, S: 0, D: 0, P: 0};
 }
 var Random = (function(randomSeed) {
  function next() {
   return Math.random();
  }
  function nextInt(n) {
   return next() * n |0;
  }
  return {
   next,
   nextInt,
   pick: a => a[nextInt(a.length)],
   shuffle: function(a) {
    for (var l = a.length; l > 1;) {
     var o = nextInt(l--);
     [a[l], a[o]] = [a[o], a[l]];
    }
    return a;
   }
  };
 })(seed);

 var idols = bots.map(x => ({
  id: x.id,
  name: x.name,
  idol: x,
  ability: checkAllot({idol: x}, "ability", 10000, false),
  improvisation: {E: 20, S: 20, D: 20, P: 20},
  skill: {E: 10, S: 10, D: 10, P: 10},
  fame: 2500
 }));
 var numIdols = bots.length;

 function calcTotal(attr, idol, skill) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i of "ESDP")
   total += idol.ability[i] * MULTIPLIER[attr][i] * (70 + Math.pow(Random.next(), 0.8) * (30 + idol.improvisation[i]) + skill * idol.skill[i]) / 100 |0;
  return total;
 }

 function battle(a, b) {
  var aDis = a.idol.disclose(b.id), bDis = b.idol.disclose(a.id), aSkill = false, bSkill = false, aWin = 0, bWin = 0, aAllot = 0, bAllot = 0;
  var aForbid = a.idol.forbid(b.id, bDis, b.ability[bDis]), bForbid = b.idol.forbid(a.id, aDis, a.ability[aDis]);
  
  var rounds = [Random.pick("ESDP"), a.idol.choose(bDis, b.ability[bDis], bForbid), b.idol.choose(aDis, a.ability[aDis], aForbid)].filter(x => x != aForbid && x != bForbid);
  while (rounds.length < 3) {
   var round = Random.pick("ESDP");
   if (round != aForbid && round != bForbid)
    rounds.push(round);
  }
  Random.shuffle(rounds);
  var result = rounds.map(function (x) {
   var aUseSkill = a.idol.skill(x), bUseSkill = b.idol.skill(x);
   var aTotal = calcTotal(x, a, !aSkill && aUseSkill), bTotal = calcTotal(x, b, !bSkill && bUseSkill);
   aSkill |= aUseSkill;
   bSkill |= bUseSkill;
   if (aTotal > bTotal) {
    aWin++;
    bAllot += 20 * aTotal / bTotal |0;
   }
   else if (bTotal > aTotal) {
    bWin++;
    aAllot += 20 * bTotal / aTotal |0;
   }
   else {
    aAllot += 30;
    bAllot += 30;
   }
   return {
    attribute: x, 
    aTotal, 
    bTotal
   };
  });
  if (aWin > bWin) {
   aAllot += 10;
   var deltaFame = 10 * Math.abs(aWin - bWin) * b.fame / a.fame |0;
   a.fame += deltaFame;
   b.fame -= deltaFame;
  }
  else if (bWin > aWin) {
   bAllot += 10;
   var deltaFame = 10 * Math.abs(aWin - bWin) * a.fame / b.fame |0;
   a.fame -= deltaFame;
   b.fame += deltaFame;
  }

  if (aAllot > 0) {
   checkAllot(b, "ability", aAllot, true);
   if (aAllot >= 10)
    checkAllot(b, "improvisation", aAllot / 10 |0, true);
  }
  if (bAllot > 0) {
   checkAllot(b, "ability", bAllot, true);
   if (bAllot >= 10)
    checkAllot(b, "improvisation", bAllot / 10 |0, true);
  }
  var aPtTotal = 0, bPtTotal = 0;
  for (var i of result) {
   aPtTotal += i.aTotal;
   bPtTotal += i.bTotal;
  }

  return {
   aID: a.id,
   bID: b.id,
   result, 
   aWin, 
   bWin,
   aPtTotal, 
   bPtTotal
  };
 }

 var totalBattleResult = {};
 idols.map(x => totalBattleResult[x.id] = {
  W: 0,
  D: 0,
  L: 0,
  BF: 0,
  BA: 0,
  BD: 0,
  PF: 0,
  PA: 0,
  PD: 0,
  pts: 0,
  rankings: []
 });

 function swissBattle() {
  var idolRanking = idols.map(x => ({
   idol: x,
   W: 0,
   D: 0,
   L: 0,
   BF: 0,
   BA: 0,
   BD: 0,
   PF: 0,
   PA: 0,
   PD: 0,
   pts: 0
  }));
  function sortRanking() {
   for (var idol of idolRanking)
    idol.lots = Random.next();
   idolRanking.sort((a, b) => b.pts - a.pts || b.W - a.W || b.BD - a.BD || b.BF - a.BF || b.PD - a.PD || b.PF - a.PF || b.lots - a.lots);
  }
  sortRanking();

  for (var i = numIdols; i > 0; i >>= 1) {
   var battles = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < numIdols - 1; j += 2) {
    var a = idolRanking[j], b = idolRanking[j + 1]
    var result = battle(a.idol, b.idol);
    battles.push(result);
    if (result.aWin > result.bWin) {
     a.W++;
     b.L++;
    }
    else if (result.bWin > result.aWin) {
     a.L++;
     b.W++;
    }
    else {
     a.D++;
     b.D++;
    }
    a.pts = a.W * 2 + a.D;
    b.pts = b.W * 2 + b.D;
    a.BF += result.aWin;
    a.BA += result.bWin;
    b.BF += result.bWin;
    b.BA += result.aWin;
    a.PF += result.aPtTotal;
    a.PA += result.bPtTotal;
    b.PF += result.bPtTotal;
    b.PA += result.aPtTotal;
    a.BD = a.BF - a.BA;
    b.BD = b.BF - b.BA;
    a.PD = a.PF - a.PA;
    b.PD = b.PF - b.PA;
   }
   if (numIdols % 2 == 1) {
    idolRanking[numIdols - 1].W++;
    idolRanking[numIdols - 1].pts += 2;
    battles.push({
     aID: idolRanking[numIdols - 1].idol.id, 
     bID: -1, 
     result: [], 
     aWin: 0, 
     bWin: 0
    });
   }
   sortRanking();
   var publicRanking = idolRanking.map(function(x) {
    var l = {};
    for (var i in x) {
     if (i == "idol")
      l.id = x.idol.id;
     else if (i != "lots")
      l[i] = x[i];
    }
    return l;
   });
   for (var idol of idols)
    idol.idol.review(publicRanking, battles);
   if (logBattles) {
        log("Battle Results:\n" + JSON.stringify(battles, null, 2));
        log("Ranking:\n" + JSON.stringify(publicRanking, null, 2));
      }
  }
  var averageFame = idols.reduce((a, b) => a + b.fame, 0) / numIdols;
  for (var i = 0; i < numIdols; i++)
   idolRanking[i].idol.fame += (Math.pow((numIdols - i) / numIdols, 1.5) * 80 + 20) * averageFame / idolRanking[i].idol.fame |0; 

  var r = 0;
  for (var p of idolRanking) {
   for (var q in p) {
    if (q != "idol" && q != "lots")
     totalBattleResult[p.idol.id][q] += p[q];
   }
   totalBattleResult[p.idol.id].rankings.push(++r);
  }
 }

 function showResult(round) {
  var temp = [...idols].sort((a, b) => b.fame - a.fame);
  var a =        " ID                 | Name                        | Fame  | Win  | Lose | Draw | BF   | BA   | BD   | Pts For   | Pts Aga.  | Pts Diff. | TP   | Tournament Rankings                                                                                         \n"
        +        "--------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+-" + "-".repeat(Math.max(20, loopRounds * 3));
  for (var i of temp) {
   a += `\n ${("" + i.id).padStart(18)} | ${i.name.padEnd(27) } | ` + ("" + i.fame).padStart(5);
   for (var j of ["W", "L", "D", "BF", "BA", "BD", "PF", "PA", "PD", "pts"])
    a += " | " + ("" + totalBattleResult[i.id][j]).padStart(j[0] == "P" ? 9 : 4);
   a += " | " + totalBattleResult[i.id].rankings.map(x => ("" + x).padStart(2)).join` `;
  }
  log("Round " + round + " results:\n" + a);
    return a;
 }

 function loop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < loopRounds; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (var k of idols) {
     checkAllot(k, "ability", 100, true);
     checkAllot(k, "improvisation", 5, true);
     var convertPlan = k.idol.convert();
     if (convertPlan) {
      var {attribute, unit} = convertPlan;
      var converted = Math.min(unit, k.improvisation[attribute] * 5);
      k.improvisation[attribute] -= converted / 5;
      k.ability[attribute] += converted;
     }
     var learnPlan = k.idol.learn();
     if (learnPlan) {
      var {attribute, unit} = learnPlan;
      var learnt = Math.min(unit, k.improvisation[attribute] / 5);
      k.improvisation[attribute] -= learnt * 5;
      k.skill[attribute] += learnt;
      if (k.skill[attribute] > ALLOT_LIMIT.skill)
       k.skill[attribute] = ALLOT_LIMIT.skill;
     }
    }
   }
   swissBattle();
   showResult(i + 1);
  }
 }

 return {
  loop,
  query(id) {
   var idol = idols.filter(x => x.id == id)[0];
   if (idol) {
    var publicIdol = {};
    for (var i in idol) {
     if (i != "idol")
      publicIdol[i] = idol[i];
    }
    return publicIdol;
   }
   else 
    return null;
  },
  showResult
 };
}

var players = 0;
function addPlayer() {
  var id = Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 53);
  $("#players").append(`
    <div class="bot" id="bot-${id}">
      <textarea cols="100" rows="10"></textarea> ${++players > 2 ? `<input type="button" value="Delete this bot" onclick="deletePlayer(${id})">` : ""}
    </div>
  `);
}

function deletePlayer(id) {
  $("#bot-" + id).remove();
  players--;
}
/*
$("#run").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.target.checkValidity();
  console.log("test");
});*/
var IdolizeMeAPI;
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cls();
  var bots = [], submissions = {};
  $(".bot").each(function(s) {
    var code = $(this).find("textarea").val();
    var botFunctionName = /function (\w+) *\(id\) *{/.exec(code);
    if (botFunctionName) {
      botFunctionName = botFunctionName[1];
      code = code.replace(/function (\w+) *\(id\) *{/, `submissions["$1"] = function(id) {`);
      eval(code);
      bots.push(new submissions[botFunctionName](+$(this).attr("id").slice(4)));
    }
  });
  IdolizeMeAPI = startIdolizeMeAPI(bots, "whatever it is we don't use seeds at all", +$("#rounds").val(), $("#logbattle").prop("checked"));
  IdolizeMeAPI.loop();
  return false;
});

addPlayer();
addPlayer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Rounds: <input id="rounds" pattern="\d+" value="6" required/><br>
  Log battle results: <input type="checkbox" id="logbattle"><br>
  Player Bots:
  <div id="players">
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add a bot" onclick="addPlayer()"><br>
  <input id="run" type="submit" value="Run simulation">
</form>
<pre id="log">
</pre>
```

You may want to open the snippet in a new page.

### Demo Bots

2 simple demo bots will be in the same contest with submitted bots, of exactly the same implementation, but with different names: One called *Yamada Ransu* (山田 乱數) and one called *Sato Midare* (佐藤 乱).

```javascript
function TheTwoSimpleDemoBotsYouAreCompetingWith(id) {
    return {
        id: id,
        name: "???",
        allot(type, amount) {        
            return {
                E: amount/4,
                S: amount/4,
                D: amount/4,
                P: amount/4
            };
        },
        review(ranking, battles) {},
        learn() {
            return {
                attribute: "ESDP"[Math.random() * 4 |0],
                unit: Math.random() * 5 |0
            };
        },
        convert() {
            return null;
        },
        disclose(rival) {
            return "ESDP"[Math.random() * 4 |0];
        },
        forbid(rival, attribute, value) {
            return "ESDP"[Math.random() * 4 |0];
        },
        choose(attribute, value, forbidden) {
            return "ESDP"[Math.random() * 4 |0];
        },
        skill(attribute) {
            return Math.random() < 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

### Winning Criteria

Submission is open for 2 weeks from the posting day, until 15:00 GMT on the end day, or until there are more than 20 submissions, whichever is later. You are welcomed to submit multiple entries during the period. After the the submission period ends, the 36 rounds will be simulated within 3 days. After the 36 rounds, the bot with the highest fame wins, and the corresponding submission will be accepted as "best answer". The simulation result will be posted.

Comment: Will we have access to the controller?

Comment: @Alion If by "controller" you mean the function which runs the rounds, sorry but no, except the `IdolizeMeAPI.query(id)`. However the data you'll need will be passed into your functions (e.g. the rankings and battle history). Please make good use of the `review()` function. You can't define global storage, but you can define local storage inside the function. I hope this may help you.

Comment: As a footnote: all 8 functions are called actively by the controller during the loop. Maybe I should add a diagram to explain this.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't what I meant. I was wondering if a runner for the game will be available for testing our bots - to debug, improve, compare against others, etc. Sort of how one was provided in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots) or [that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest) challenge.

Comment: @Alion Oh I see. I didn't consider that when I was writing the KotH, but I think I'd like to make a test snippet simulating several rounds for a smaller group of players, if the post isn't too long yet.

Comment: BTW may I ask how long can my post be? I checked the markdown and it's now @14.4kB

Comment: IIRC, the post length is capped at 65536 characters. If you plan on providing a controller for players to use to test their bots, I would highly recommend [Dave's JS KotH Framework](https://github.com/davidje13/koth-webplayer). It takes a while to get used to, but it does quite a lot of work for you, without restricting your challenge too much.

Comment: @Alion Oh thanks, I'll go and have a look. And it seems there is still quite a bunch of vacancy, so I'll add the test drive into the sandbox first.

Comment: @Alion I've added the snippet to the post.

Answer (score 1):

## Not All Sums Are Equal

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[numerical-analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis)[sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sum)

#### Introduction

When computing the sum of a list of floating point values, the order in which we add up the summands matters. A good way to reduce errors is beginning with the summand with the least modulus and working your way up to the numbers with a greater modulus. As an illustrative example, let us assume our computer uses floating point numbers that comprise 2 (decimal) digits \$m_1,m_2\$ for the mantissa (and a sufficiently large number of digits for the exponent \$e\$.) These represent a number \$0.m_1m_2 \cdot 10^e\$. Let us consider the list

```
[0.1, 0.009, 0.009]
```

The exact result would obviously be \$0.118\$, and the best approximation in our computer therefore \$0.12\$. But if we actually tell the computer to sum those numbers, it will truncate all intermediate results, so it will get:

```
 (0.1 + 0.009) + 0.009 = 0.1 + 0.009 = 0.1
```

If we use the recipe from above and sort the list by the modulus first, we get

```
(0.009 + 0.009) + 0.1 = 0.018 + 0.1 = 0.11
```

which is already closer to the exact result. So we see that any permutation in the order of the summation might produce a different sum. In order to estimate the possible error we're interested in the difference between the greatest and the least sum we can get by just using a permutations of the original list. This is the task of this challenge.

#### Examples

The following examples assume that you use IEEE-754 `double` numbers in your implementation. You can of course use other implementations, but the results might be different:

```
[0.0140534017661288 0.50942429920538 1 1.96300019759529 71.1571487560538]
1.42108547152020e-14
[-0.447570988743782 -0.30397649549556 0 0.765285061877593 3.30425088014391]
8.88178419700125e-16
```

Comment: 1. The decimal example only works because it's using a bad rounding mode. With a good rounding mode which gives an answer with half an ULP, both orders would give `0.12`. 2. The example is not very clear on what the inputs and outputs are.

Answer (score 1):

## [Posted: Is this number secretly Fibonacci?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174907/56470)

Answer (score 1):

## Unjagged my array

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

---

Given a jagged array of integers, rearrange the integers such that

- The shape of the jagged array is unchanged, and
- The jaggedness of each subarray is minimized.

Here "jaggedness" is defined as the sum of the absolute differences in each subarray. If an array has only one element, then the jaggedness of that array must be 0, since there are no absolute differences to consider.

We only care about the differences in elements in the same subarray. So for example:

```
[[1, 2], [100]]
```

has a jaggedness of **1**, since the first array has a jaggedness of \$abs(1-2) = 1\$ and the second array has a jaggedness of 0. We don't care that the difference between 2 and 100 is 98 since they are different subarrays.

Here's an example:

```
Input: [[16, 8], [15], [4, 42, 23]]
jaggedness of input: [abs(16 - 8)] + [0] + [abs(4 - 42) + abs(42 - 23)] =
8 + 38 + 19 = 65

One possible output: [[4, 8], [42], [15, 16, 23]]
jaggedness of this output: [abs(4 - 8)] + [0] + [abs(15 - 16) + abs(16 - 23)] = 4 + 1 + 7 = 12
```

Of course, this is one possible output. Any of these outputs would also have a jaggedness of 12:

```
[[4, 8], [42], [23, 16, 15]]
[[8, 4], [42], [15, 16, 23]]
[[8, 4], [42], [23, 16, 15]]
```

### Clarifications

- The input will always contain non-negative integers. The input will also always have a length `>= 1`, and all of the subarrays will have a length `>= 1`. This means that you must handle inputs as small as `[[n]]`, where **n** is any non-negative integer.
- If the input is already arranged to be as smooth as possible, it is acceptable for your code to output the integers in a different order, as long as this new order has the same jaggedness. For example, if the input was

  ```
  [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
  ```

  then your program may return the input unchanged, or it may return

  ```
  [[5, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
  ```

  or any of the other arrangements with jaggedness **3**.

## Fastest code

This is a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, so the submission with the shortest run time for a hidden test case will win. I will use 2 different test cases with different shapes, and your score will be the sum of the time for each. (I haven't yet decided how large these test cases should be. I might adjust them once submissions come in so that it takes an appropriate amount of time.)

All submissions will be tested on my machine:

- Windows 10
- i7-4790k
- 8 GB RAM

You can use any language that is freely available on Windows 10. Please also provide instructions for running your submission. I will test each submission at my soonest convenience after it's posted, and then comment an unofficial score. After 1 week, I will test every submission, and post a leaderboard.

## Test Cases

These test cases were generated with and verified by [a python brute-forcer](https://tio.run/##XVJBbsMgELz7FRyhopat9GQp1576AyuKcEwSUgwIsKr08@4uYCeNDzZmZ2ZnB9w9Xq3ZLYuanPWReGFGO1XlT0Xpo7U6VNUoz@QijfQiSio4GTg57dumYV1F4NFkT/pDldZn64kiyqDYBcAFkmC1cE6akfa5UY0fZSJtQI4l5vHBfMG00JWxA8tdvIyzN0Rna5PVI9WchKtwsjQ08ie7Wg1qFSLVbDMZ5uELtrBh4j18AnVzqmtnHW2e3BXeixPgZC@Dn6M8AvoEw3tf3Jy1iOAhQK5ypGGesMbBHsuG0muQIX5m4KQM3fKvnfTTHEVU1gSKUoyTb3nfazENoyC6CyfrJV1jwLZFV5iAalhY1XP9n3lAQXhJA5ZsCyINlPd1GaQwcII0xRDo7V3leBQnN0zoVzkoDn333h445tW3HQy6po4QOIeqwlPZbtWOkw9O8E5VzuOBIySv3p4z1Ywtyx8).

```
Input: [[1, 2, 9], [10, 11]]
Output: [[9, 10, 11], [1, 2]] (jaggedness 3)

Input: [[4, 8, 15], [16], [23, 42]]
Output: [[4, 8, 15], [16], [23, 42]] (jaggedness 30)

Input: [[45, 98, 9, 46], [48, 53, 59], [13], [38, 94]]
Output: [[45, 46, 48, 53], [9, 13, 38], [59], [94, 98]] (jaggedness 41)
```

Note that none of these test cases show the only acceptable answer, merely *one* acceptable answer. For example, any output would remain valid if a subarray was reversed.

Answer (score 1):

[floating-point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) [logic-gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates) [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

### Toy floating point coprocessor: ceil

Summary: implement the ceiling function for 16-bit IEEE 754 floating point numbers in logic gates, using as few gates as you can.

#### 16-bit IEEE 754 floating point

For a more detailed description, see [Wikipedia:Half-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).

The 16 bits are divided into three chunks: sign (1 bit), exponent (5 bits), mantissa (10 bits).

- The sign is `0` for positive numbers and `1` for negative numbers.
- The exponent is *biased*: interpret as an unsigned 5-bit number and subtract 15 to get the true exponent. Special cases are described below.
- The mantissa is an unsigned 10-bit number with an implicit leading 11th bit which depends on the exponent.

If the exponent is `00000` (corresponding to -15), the number is *subnormal*. The implicit leading bit of the mantissa is `0`, but there's a bonus factor of two, so the interpreted value is \$(-1)^{\textrm{sign}}\; 2^{-14}\; 0.\textrm{mantissa}\$, or (expanding the \$0.\textrm{mantissa}\$ binary notation) \$(-1)^{\textrm{sign}}\; 2^{-24}\; \textrm{mantissa}\$.

If the exponent is `11111` (corresponding to 16), the number is either *infinite* (if the mantissa is `0000000000`) or a NaN.

For all other exponents, the implicit leading bit of the mantissa is `1`, so the interpreted value is \$(-1)^{\textrm{sign}}\; 2^{\textrm{exponent}-15}\; 1.\textrm{mantissa}\$, expanded to \$(-1)^{\textrm{sign}}\; 2^{\textrm{exponent}-25}\; (2^{10} + \textrm{mantissa})\$

#### Ceiling function

The ceiling function maps real numbers to integers, rounding up. So if the input value is an integer, the output value is unchanged; if the input value is not an integer, the output value is the smallest integer greater than the input value.

Examples:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \textrm{ceil}(x) \\
\hline
-1 & -1 \\
-0.5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0.00001 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
1.8 & 2 \\
\end{array}$$

#### Corner cases

Given an infinity, the output must be the same infinity.

Given a NaN, the output must be a NaN, but it can be any NaN.

IEEE 754 floating point systems have signed zeroes. Given a zero, the output must be the same zero.

#### Gates and scoring

You must implement a logic gate with 16 inputs and 16 outputs. You may use any two-input logic gates and you may mix different types of logic gates. We idealise the gates: don't worry about things like fan-out limitations or propagation delays. The score is the number of gates, and the fewer the better. If you choose to explain your design by giving code which uses bitwise operation on integers, be sure to document clearly how many bits are being processed by each operation.

#### Test cases

TODO, but will cover both infinities, both signed zeroes, positive and negative subnormals, positive and negative integer values, positive and negative non-integer values, and a NaN.

Comment: I assume 2-to-1 gate, or 2-to-any?

Answer (score 1):

## [Calculate your Icy Score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175875/72535)

Answer (score 1):

## Minimize your standard deviation

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

The standard deviation of a collection of numbers is calculated in the following manner:

1. Find the arithmetic mean of the collection.
2. Find the difference of each item from the mean.
3. Square each difference and sum them.
4. Divide by the number of items in the collection minus 1.
5. Take the square root.

Or, expressed mathematically:

$$ s = \sqrt{ \frac{ \sum^N_{i=1} (x_i - \bar x)^2 }{N - 1} }, $$

where \$N\$ is the number of items, \$x_i\$ is the \$i\$th item, and \$\bar x\$ is the arithmetic mean.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program or function in your language of choice that, given an array of bytes, calculates the standard deviation of the array. The catch: the standard deviation of the bytes in your code will be added to your score.

#### Rules

- Input may be in any reasonable format (e.g. numbers separated by newlines or commas, an actual array or buffer, etc.)
- You may assume that the items in the input are all integers \$0 \le n < 256\$.
- You may assume that there are at least two integers in the input.
- The output or return value must be the standard deviation of the array as calculated above, accurate to at least 2 decimal places (i.e. \$ \pm 0.005 \$)

### Test cases

(test cases to come)

### Scoring

The score of your code is its length in bytes, plus the standard deviation of its bytes (i.e. \$N + s\$). **The code with the lowest score in each language wins.**

(If you somehow find a language with a 1-byte built-in that fulfills the challenge, your score will just be 1. In the impossible case of a 0-byte built-in, your score will be \$0 + \frac{0}{-1} = 0\$.)

### Sandbox questions

- Is this too similar to the vanilla [standard deviation challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60901/42545)?
- For non-golfing languages that primarily use ASCII, the standard deviation will likely be much lower than the byte count, leading to golfing the code being significantly more important than reducing \$s\$. How could this best be combated? \$\sqrt N + s\$? \$N + s^2\$? (where \$N\$ is the length of the code) Obviously I wouldn't want to just use \$s\$, as you could just append one byte (e.g. `;` in many languages) over and over to lower it arbitrarily.

Comment: Standard deviation was my enemy in algebra.

Comment: It seems difficult to create a scoring that penalizes appending redundant bytes and that the shortest solution wouldn't always win.

Answer (score 1):

## Classify arity of verbs inside trains in J [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [j](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j)

Related: [Clearly parenthesize APL trains](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150380/78410)

### Background

J is an APL-family language. While it inherits the basic train syntax from APL (take a look at the linked challenge above), J is more versatile with the introduction of `[:`, `&` and `@` among many others. But the problem is, the more features a tacit expression has, the harder it is to read and understand what it does. Even worse, most of the built-in verbs have both monadic and dyadic usage, and some of them have two completely different meanings! So let's build a helper to classify the arity of verbs.

#### Notations

- `#` is a monadic verb.
- `+` is a dyadic verb.
- `[` is a special symbol called "cap" which can appear at specific positions inside a train.
- `@` and `&` are conjunctions, which take two verbs on both sides and form a single verb.
- `x` and `y` are left and right arguments to a given train, respectively. If `x` is missing, the train is called monadically (with one argument `y`); otherwise, dyadically (with both arguments).

#### Basics

- In a train of verbs, the last 3 verbs are recursively grouped.
- Conjunctions bind from left to right.

#### Rules

```
Monadic
(# + #) y   =>  (# y) + (# y)
(+ #) y     =>  y + (# y)
([ # #) y   =>  # (# y)
(+ # + #) y =>  (+ (# + #)) y
(# + # + # + #) y => (# + (# + (# + #))) y
(# + [ # # + #) y => (# + ([ # (# + #))) y

Dyadic
x (+ + +) y   =>  (x + y) + (x + y)
x (+ #) y     =>  x + (# y)
x ([ # +) y   =>  # (x + y)
x (+ # + #) y =>  x (+ (# + #)) y    <= the 3-group is run monadically
x (+ + + + + + +) y => x (+ + (+ + (+ + +))) y
x (+ + [ # + + +) y => x (+ + ([ # (+ + +))) y

Conjunction &
(#&#) y   => # (# y)
x (+&#) y => (# x) + (# y)

Conjunction @
(#@#) y   => # (# y)
x (#@+) y => # (x + y)
```

#### How to determine arity of each verb

```
   (?  (? ?&?@?    ?) ?) y
=> (# d(? ?&?@?    ?) #) y    monadic 3-train: # + #
=> (#  (+ d?&?@?   +) #) y    dyadic 3-train:  + + +
=> (#  (+ d(?&?)@? +) #) y    conjunction binds from left; arity is determined from right
=> (#  (+ m(?&?)@+ +) #) y    dyadic `@`:  #@+
=> (#  (+  (#&#)@+ +) #) y    monadic `&`: #&#
```

### Challenge

Given an expression that represents the structure of a J train, determine the arity of every verb in the expression.

### Input & output

TBD

### Test cases

TBD

### Scoring & winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest valid program or function in each language wins.

Answer (score 1):

## mAkE a StRiNg EpIc [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Now that the meme is mostly dead, we can have this challenge. It's pretty simple: take a string (either as stdin or a parameter to a function), and change the case to alternate capital and lowercase letters, starting with lowercase. Examples:

```
"Hello, World!" -> "hElLo, WoRlD!"
"PPCG" -> "pPcG"
"Ok now this is epic" -> "oK nOw ThIs Is EpIc"
"" -> ""
```

### Rules:

- Can take input as a parameter to a function or as stdin
- Punctuation marks are left alone
- Must not take any input other than the input string
- It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Sandbox questions:

- The obvious one: is it a duplicate? I don't think so, but I don't know for sure.
- Is it too trivial for some languages?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is actually not a bad challenge idea!

Comment: What happens with the comma in `"Hello, World!"`?

Comment: You may want to clarify that non-letters are skipped.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122783/alternate-the-case

Answer (score 1):

## Find the best K year period to have invested

A stock index is a way of measuring the overall performance of the stock prices of a group of companies (which may change from time to time). An example from the US is called the S&P 500. An index fund is an investment that grows at the same rate as the underlying index.

Here are the annual returns for a hypothetical S&P 500 stock index fund for each calendar year from 1928 to 2017, expressed as a multiplier. So in 1927 you might say "the index went up by 37.88%" which I've represented here by 1.3788.

```
1.3788, 0.8809, 0.7152, 0.5293, 0.8485, 1.4659, 0.9406, 1.4137, 1.2792, 0.6141,  1.2521, 0.9455, 0.8471, 0.8214, 1.1243,  1.1945, 1.138, 1.3072, 0.8813, 1,  0.9935, 1.1026, 1.2178, 1.1646, 1.1178,  0.9338, 1.4502, 1.264, 1.0262, 0.8569,  1.3806, 1.0848, 0.9703, 1.2313, 0.8819,  1.1889, 1.1297, 1.0906, 0.8691, 1.2009,  1.0766, 0.8864, 1.001, 1.1079, 1.1563,  0.8263, 0.7028, 1.3155, 1.1915, 0.885,  1.0106, 1.1231, 1.2577, 0.9027, 1.1476,  1.1727, 1.014, 1.2633, 1.1462, 1.0203,  1.124, 1.2725, 0.9344, 1.2631, 1.0446,  1.0706, 0.9846, 1.3411, 1.2026, 1.3101,  1.2667, 1.1953, 0.8986, 0.8696, 0.7663,  1.2638, 1.0899, 1.03, 1.1362, 1.0353,  0.6151, 1.2345, 1.1278, 1, 1.1341,  1.296, 1.1139, 0.9927, 1.0954, 1.1942
```

### Challenge

Given as inputs this array of annual returns and an array of size \$1\le K \le 89\$ non-negative real numbers (the amounts to invest in each year), write a program or function that outputs what would have been the best \$K\$ year period to have invested each amount in the array in this hypothetical index fund, assuming the returns from each year are reinvested at the beginning of the next year.

### Rules

1. This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the fewest bytes in each language wins.
2. If you don't like the way I've represented the array of annual returns, you can change them to any other array of 89 numbers that you prefer. (SANDBOX NOTE: This is intended to allow for some input flexibility (people might prefer to use the given array minus 1, or the cumulative returns) but not *too* much (so that people don't cheat and change the array to some multi-dimensional monster that nearly solves the whole problem).)
3. You can output the best \$K\$ year period in any consistent manner (e.g. 0-indexed or 1-indexed, the first or the last period to have invested, the entire range of years, the actual years themselvs, etc.) but you need to say what your output represents if it isn't obvious.
4. In case of a tie, output any or all correct answers.

### Example

Suppose the array consisted of \$[ 10000, 20000, 30000]\$.

If you had invested these amounts in 1928, 1929, and 1930 (the 1-indices 1, 2, and 3) you would have ended up with \$42743.10\$.

But if you had invested those amounts in 2015, 2016, and 2017 (the 1-indices 87, 88, and 89) you would have ended up with \$66722.66\$.

It turns out the *best* three year period to have invested these amounts would have been 1995, 1996, and 1997 (1-indices 68, 69, and 70).

### Test cases

1-indexed, first year of optimal period

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]                          ->  68
[ 1 ]                                ->   6
*any array of length 89*             ->   1
[ 1, 1 ]                             ->  27
[ 1, 2 ]                             ->   8
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]  ->  63
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]        ->  64
* 1 repeated 20 times *              ->  53
```

Comment: I remember there being a challenge about when to invest before. Have you checked for duplicates?

Comment: @lirtosiast I did check. I did not see any non-King of the Hill investment questions. That being said it's not always easy to find dupes.

Answer (score 1):

## Exploring generalzations of Cheryl's birthday problem

In this challenge we will generalize the Cheryl's birthday problem to arbitrary finite subsets of pairs of integers

## Challenge

Cheryl gives Albert and Bernard a finite collection of pairs of integers S. Cheryl chooses an element (x, y) from S and tells x to Albert and y to Bernard. Assume everyone speaks truthfully.

Albert says: "I don't know what x and y are, but I know that Bernard doesn't know". More precisely: Albert does not know what y is, but using only the information given in the first paragraph, the elements of S and the value x, Albert is certain that Bernard doesn't know what x is.

Bernard says: "At first I didn't know what x and y were ,but now I do". - That is, before Albert said anything, Bernard doesn't know what x and y are, but after Albert spoke, Bernard knew.

Albert says: "Now I also know what x and y are".

Your task is to write a computer program that takes as input the set S, and outputs a list of all possible values for the (x, y) that Cheryl chose, in any order. (therefore you must use a programming language that can handle lists of pairs of numbers). If there is no solution or that conversation is impossible, output an empty list.

This challenge is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)]

Output:

> []

There is no solution to this problem because the conversation is impossible. Knowing either x or y will result in knowing the other one. Therefore, it's impossible for Bernard to know y but not x.

Input:

> [(5,15),(5,16),(5,19),(6,17),(6,18),(7,14),(7,16),(8,14),(8,15),(8,17)]

Output:

> [(7,16)]

This is the original problem.

Input:

> [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]

Output:

> []

The conversation is impossible as Bernard cannot deduce x from y and the fact that Albert knows that Bernard does not know x.

Input:

> [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,3)]

Output:

> [(2,2)]

If x was 1, then Albert cannot be sure that Bernard doesn't know x, because if y was 0, then Bernard would know that x was 1. Similarly for if x was 3. Therefore x was 2 or 4.

After Albert spoke, Bernard can eliminate x=1 and x=3, and then he can deduce what x was. If Bernard had y = 1 or 3, then Bernard could not distinguish between (2,1) and (4,1), or between (2,3) and (4,3). As Bernard knew, we must have y = 2. After Bernard spoke, Albert knew that y=2, and x=2.

Answer (score 1):

Output [The End Poem](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vywrgkvhwq/). Outputting as array, or with only one `\n` or three `\n` to separate sentences, etc. are fine. Shortest code win.

Upvote to prefer: You can take an input containing [all letters in lowercase](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RfgQYFzgnH/) or uppercase

Downvote to prefer: You can take an input containing all letters in their original cases(upper/lower)

P.S. The two old choices are too similar

Comment if duplicate, fell the length is bad, etc

Comment: I don't see why this isn't a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're given the text as input and only need to insert the spaces.

Comment: Optionally, (in the second option) you're allowed to encode (part of) the data into the case of the input.

Comment: "Upvote/Downvote" to prefer isn't actually the right approach for the sandbox, votes indicate likelihood of the challenge being well-received on main.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Any other suggestion?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The "right" way it was doesn't work fine, usually too inconsistant to main; also occupying the vote for other usage make like/dislike go to comment for clearer reason

Comment: I vote all letters in their original cases. Inserting spaces and punctuation is enough of a challenge in itself.

Comment: @lirtosiast Uppercase only be first letter, `I` and `PLAYERNAME` I see. Taking input in original cases mean possible ability to learn from cases how to insert spaces

Answer (score 1):

### Fully modular C program [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Modularity means that instead of writing one big long procedure, we break up our logic into small, composable functions. We all know that modularity is a good thing. But why settle for a good thing when you can have the *best* thing? Let's make our programs  *fully modular*. This means that each function must contain zero assignment statements and no more than one function call and one binary operator (if it contains more than that, that's a sign your function is getting too long and you need to break it up).

Example 1:

```
int multiply_add(int a, int b, int c) { return a * b + c; }
```

might become

```
int multiply(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int multiply_add(int a, int b, int c) { return multiply(a, b) + c; }
```

Example 2:

```
int foo(int x)
    int y = x + 3;
    bar(y, y);
}
```

might become

```
int bar2(int y) { return bar(y, y); }
int foo(int x) { return bar2(x + 3); }
```

**Sandbox note**: I am working on the [fully modular C verifier](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17153/30688) question before this one.

Comment: Is there a name pool or we need to check if a name is used?

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is the input a less than fully modular program, and the required output any valid fully modular program that has identical behaviour? Also wondering if the score will be length of the solution code, or length of the output, or something else

Comment: @l4m2 You'll be responsible for generating new identifiers that don't clash. Though I'm thinking about making it actually a program where only the behavior of `main()` needs to be preserved.

Comment: @trichoplax Yes to the first question, and standard code golf with length of the modularizer.

Comment: Sounds interesting, theres going to be a lot of breaking sum_stuff(return a + b + c + d) down into sum_stuff(sum_pair(sum_pair(a, b), sum_pair(c, d))) like rearrangement.

Comment: Needs more examples. I suggest Fibonacci and integer power.

Comment: I suggest you name the challenge "Monadic C"

Answer (score 1):

## Sequences that sum to n

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

<sup>Barely too late for Fibonacci Day :(</sup>

Given a positive integer `n`, your challenge is to output a sequence of `1` and `2` that adds to `n`. For example, for input `8`, acceptable outputs include `11111111`, `2222`, and `121211`.

It's not quite that simple, though. Given `n`, the number of possible outputs is the `n`<sup>th</sup> term of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://oeis.org/A000045) (starting with `F(0) = F(1) = 1`); you must return each with equal probability. This means that the following Python 3 is invalid:

```
def foo(n):
  out = ""    # String output is by no means required.
  while n:
    a = min(random.randint(1, 2), n)
    out += str(a)
    n -= a
  return out
```

While this will return each allowed result with nonzero probability and everything else with zero probability, the distribution is not uniform. In particular, `foo(3)` is twice as likely to be `21` is it is to be `111` or `12`.

Standard [IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884) and [loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) rules apply. Output is flexible, but you must use 1 and 2, not 0 and 1 or some other weird thing.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (in bytes) wins! Happy golfing!

Comment: Do you think there will be a choice of strategy for many languages? I have a hard time coming up with a language where creating each string and choosing one uniformly isn't the best approach. This isn't a huge problem, and otherwise I think this is a fine challenge.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I could see someone perhaps using a function of the remaining value to tweak probabilities, something that would choose `2` only a third of the time for `n = 3`. Not sure, though—I haven't yet given this a try :/

Answer (score 1):

## Given element count, minimum GCD and maximum LCM, compute the number of distinct integer arrays

Inspired by a question in Turkish National Computing Olympiad.

You are given 3 numbers: n, x and y.

Compute the number of distinct integer arrays with n elements whose GCD is greater than x and lcm is less than y.

Test cases: (n,x,y -> result)

```
1,1,10 -> 10 // there are 10 1 element arrays with gcd>=1 and lcm<=10, which are [1],[2],[3],...[10].
```

I can not add much test cases because I could not solve the question (well, I got 10 points by writing a python script which outputs a c++ file which hardcodes the first subtask, but I think the does not count.), please help with test cases.

Rules: i/o is flexible. Standard loopholes are not allowed.

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in every language wins.

Comment: Should the specification be "greater than or equal"/"less than or equal"?

Comment: But you still can make small test cases, right...

Comment: greater than/equal and less than or equal. also, I can only generate cases with n=1 in reasonable time. i may try to write a n=2 or n=3 test-case too if that helps

Comment: "*Standard loopholes are allowed*" - please rethink that.

Comment: ok, now they are not allowed

Comment: Be advised that the shortest solution in many languages will be "filter all N element subsets of numbers less than Y by whether they meet the criteria" which will take Y^N time to run.

Answer (score 1):

### Solve Newcomb's paradox [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Newcomb's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomb%27s_paradox) is a problem that has been stumping philosopher's for decades. And, as anyone who uses reddit knows, a problem posed by a philosopher is best solved by a software engineer.

In Newcomb's paradox, you are presented with two boxes, A and B. You can either take B or take A and B. A contains $1000. B contains $0 if a predictor predicts you will take box A and $1000000 if it predicts you will not take box A.

For this challenge, the predictor will be an execution function or command, such as python's [exec](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/) function, or the bash eval command. Therefore, you must use a programming language that has one.

Therefore, to solve Newcomb's paradox your program must:

- Output the string "B" when run with an eval function.
- Output the string "A+B" when run normally.

This will allow you to win $10001000.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

Comment: Adequately defining "*an eval function*" is notoriously difficult, and that lack of clarity is compounded here by the implicit quantifier in "*run with an eval function*". Does this mean that there must exist a function which takes a string and executes it as code, and the answer should state what this function is; or does it mean that the function must detect when run by *any* function which takes a string and evaluates it as code?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking of a specific eval function that the answer specifies. It should be built into the language though (since its trivial if you make your own). You are right though about the definition of an eval function being vague. Do you think the challenge is salvageable with some modifications?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be good to get some input from a LISPer (where AIUI eval is trivial). I think that .Net is probably an example of a situation where "built in" is imprecise (I'm not sure that there is exactly an eval method for strings in the standard library, but I think it's fairly straightforward to write one with `System.CodeDom.Compiler`, and third party libraries exist which do that). Then there's a question as to whether an eval method must accept a string, or whether detecting the difference between `f()` and `f.invoke([])` (JavaScript, I think) or similar counts.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am thinking of eliminating the eval function aspect entirely. Any ideas as to two different conditions under which to run a program that would be in the spirit of Newcomb's paradox (in a cheeky way)?

Answer (score 1):

## Sums of Bessel Polynomial Coefficients [WIP]

This is https://oeis.org/A001515.

Interesting alternate characterizations include:

> Equivalently, number of sequences of n unlabeled items such that each item occurs just once or twice (cf. A105749). - David Applegate, Dec 08 2008
>
> Numerator of (n+1)-th convergent to 1+tanh(1). - Benoit Cloitre, Dec 20 2002
>
> a(n) is also the numerator of the continued fraction sequence beginning with 2 followed by 3 and the remaining odd numbers: [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,...]. - Gil Broussard, Oct 07 2009
>
> Also, number of scenarios in the Gift Exchange Game when a gift can be stolen at most once.

Answer (score 1):

## Is the array sorted?

Inspired in part by [Creative ways to determine of an array is sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22333/creative-ways-to-determine-if-an-array-is-sorted).

Given an array of integers, find out if the array is sorted. This challenge is as simple as it sounds. I'm surprised that I couldn't find a question like this on PPCG. I'm aware that a lot of golfing languages will have short solutions, but perhaps this question could allow you to showcase a language that's more esoteric than it is practical?

### Input

An array of integers, or a sequence of integers if your language doesn't support arrays.

### Output

`Truthy` if the array is sorted, `falsey` otherwise

### Examples

```
[1, 2, 3] => true
[3, 2, 1] => false
[1, 1, 1] => true
[] => true
[1] => true
[-3, -2, -1] => true
[-1, -2, -3] => false
[1, 2, 1] => false
[1, 1, 0] => false
```

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), get ready to trim off some bytes! Happy golfing!

### For the sandbox

I have searched thoroughly for a question like this, but I haven't been able to find this question posted previously. If it exists, or if it is too similar to another question, please link the question or comment why this question should/shouldn't be posted.

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Comment: People don't post trivial challenges because it's not interesting to do in most languages. However having trivial challenges is not a too bad thing for esoteric languages like Brain-Flak. Dodos will still have great difficulty handling negative numbers.

Comment: Good point. Since this challenge will mainly be interesting in esoteric languages, I suggest restricting the input to positive integers. It won't make the challenge any different for languages with signed integer types, while allowing other languages to participate without implementing a new number type.

Answer (score 1):

## Compressed RSA keys

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

Silly cops-and-robbers idea.

As computers get more powerful, RSA keys have grown longer and longer to maintain security. This makes it difficult to:

- hand out your encryption key on business cards
- recite it over the telephone
- quickly scribble it down when you meet someone at a bar
- etc.

But we are all programmers (maybe even that someone that you met in a bar), so let's come up with RSA keys that can be generated by very short programs. We should be careful, though, that these keys remain resistant to cracking.

#### Cops

Write a short program (or function) that outputs an *RSA key*. For this challenge, an RSA key is just any positive integer less than \$2^{1024}\$ that has a non-trivial divisor.

Your program must:

- take no input
- output the same number every time it's run
- finish quickly (a few seconds at most)

Post your program, its language, and what it outputs.

Also, prove that you can use it as an RSA key. Provide a SHA-256 hash of a string that lists all the prime factors of your key.

#### Robbers

Crack the RSA keys! If an RSA key is the integer \$n\$; find any integer \$1<d<n\$ that divides \$n\$.

#### Scoring

A key is vulnerable to cracking for 7 days after it's posted. After that, it is considered safe and eligible for scoring.

**Cops:** The shortest uncracked program wins.

**Robbers:** Most cracks wins.

(Related: [compress RSA public keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/how-much-can-we-compress-rsa-public-keys) on crypto.SE)

Comment: What's to prevent me from feeding random numbers into a 700-bit hash function until I get a semiprime, which I factor on huge amounts of cloud computing time and then post? No one can crack it unless they have a bigger computer.

Comment: Nothing, I guess. It might cost you a lot of money to do that, though.

Comment: Also for what it's worth, not all semiprimes have large factors, so you'd have to factor many of them until you get a strong one. The robber only has to factor the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Not a challenge, but not certain of the wording so trying it out here:

---

## Tips for golfing in JSLint

[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

What general tips do you have for golfing in JavaScript restricted to satisfying [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) with default options? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to JSLint (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Answer (score 1):

## Minimal Substring Lookup Table

A fairly common component of code golf challenges is taking input as a string, and finding the index of that string within an array. A common way to golf that action is to instead store a substring of each item in the array, and take the same substring of the input to use when looking up the index. For example, [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141675/71434) has some fairly large strings that need to be indexed, but [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141677/71434) found that each item could be uniquely identified by its 4th letter.

#### Challenge

Find the shortest substring that, when applied to each string in the input, results in a new set of unique strings.

#### Input

- Input is list of strings in any [default format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/71434)
- The strings will consist of [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) characters.
- The strings will not have trailing spaces
- There will be no duplicate strings

#### Output

- Output should be a list of the shortened strings after applying the substring
- If outputting indexes, 0-indexing or 1-indexing may be used.
- When strings have different lengths, substrings exceeding the length of some lines may be handled any of these ways:

  - Truncate to the available characters, e.g. `["abc","acd","ab"] => ["bc","cd","b"]`
  - Pad shorter strings with spaces, e.g. `["abc","acd","ab"] => ["bc","cd","b "]`. Note that input strings can contain spaces which need to be taken into account, so `["ab c","acdc","ab"]` must not become `["b ","cd","b "]`.
  - Wrap back to the start of the shorter string, e.g. `["abc","acd","ab"] => ["bc","cd","ba"]`. Note that even with this method it is not necessary to look for substrings where every string wraps; the starting index should always be within the length of the longest input string.

***Sandbox questions***

- Should I restrict the input strings to only a subset of printable ASCII?
- Should I enforce one specific behavior for handling shorter strings? Requiring wrapping would let the challenge look for even shorter solutions requiring full wrapping, e.g. `["aba","ab"] => ["a","b"]`, but I don't want languages with different default substring implementations to need a lot of work just to get the wrapping working.
- I used the term "substring" as something that is "applied" to a string to get the shortened version, but I know that's extremely wrong. Is there a better way to phrase this?
- [This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48274/71434) is related, but uses arbitrary substrings rather than aligned substrings. Should I mention it somewhere?

Comment: "*Should I enforce one specific behavior for handling shorter strings?*" - Personally, I'd say yes.

Comment: I think it would be better to output the position and length of the substring, rather than every substring.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just say that all input strings have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do not not not not make a filter that doesn't not not not get rid of these words!

Tags: code-golf

Your program has to scan each run of "not"s in a sentence, and if the number of "not"s is odd, then replace it with only one "not". If it is even, replace it with the empty string.

Notes:

- The "not"s are case-insensitive, so your input may be "not" or "Not" or more.
- The input may only be taken in as a string.

Test cases:

```
 Don't not not -->  Don't
 not not not a not not  -->  not a
 NoT nOt not NOT noT a Not nOt noT  -->  not a not
hello notnot anot not anota not not not --> hello a anota not
```

Comment: We've had a very similar challenge before. On my phone so can't search properly for it to determine if it would be similar *enough* to be a dupe target.

Comment: Oh, let me see that then.

Comment: So, input and output as a string? Would list of words be acceptable input/output?

Comment: @BMO List of words is not a valid format

Comment: So, should I make this a question?

Comment: What exactly counts as a `not`? Can it be part of another word? Do the `not`s have to be separated from each other by a single space?

Comment: @12Me21 it can be part of another word

Answer (score 1):

### Piano Scale Fingering

There are 12 different major scales on the piano, which have similar, but not identical, fingering. Furthermore, the fingering for each hand is slightly different.

The fingers of each hand are numbererd starting at 1 for the thumb. Each note usually takes the next finger in turn. For the left hand playing an ascending scale, this means that the numbers decrease, while for the right hand the numbers increase.

Of course you will run out of fingers before you get to the end of the scale. For the left hand, this means that when you get to the thumb you need to start again with one of the other fingers, while for the right hand this means that when you get to a certain finger you need to start again with the thumb.

Although there are eight notes in an octave, the part that repeats in the middle of a scale is seven, which is a prime number. Scales are therefore normally played using the repeatying sequnces `4321321` in the left hand and `1231234` in the right hand; the little finger is only used to avoid switching to the thumb on the first or last note respectively. Other adjustments also apply at the very start and end of the scale.

There are a couple of rules which work for most scales. The first rule is that you try to play the tonic with the thumb except at the appropriate end of the scale when you use the little finger. If you can't follow that rule then with the right hand you use the thumb when switching from a black note to a white note; with the left hand you aim for the thumb to land on a white note just before a black note.

Here is a full list of all 12 keys and their fingerings:

```
 #  Key Left Hand       Right Hand
-6  Gb  432132143213212 234123423412345
-5  Db  321432132143212 231234123123412
-4  Ab  321432132143212 231231234123123
-3  Eb  321432132143212 212341231234123
-2  Bb  321432132143212 212312341231234
-1  F   543213214321321 123412341231234
 0  C   543213214321321 123123412312345
 1  G   543213214321321 123123412312345
 2  D   543213214321321 123123412312345
 3  A   543213214321321 123123412312345
 4  E   543213214321321 123123412312345
 5  B   432143213214321 123123412312345
 6  F#  432132143213212 234123123412345
```

Please write a program function which takes as input the key (or #, which is the number of sharps in the key, or the negation of the number of flats in the key) of a scale and a flag (e.g. `L` or `R`) for which hand, and output the fingering for two octaves as above. (For longer scales you simply repeat the middle 7 digits so I don't see the utility of asking you to output an arbitrary number of octaves.)

Note that Gb is enharmonic to F# on the piano but you might find it easier to support one rather than the other. Please indicate which one your answer supports.

As an alternative to writing a single function I will also allow two named functions (one for each hand) but not two lambdas. The 1 byte per extra file penalty applies if you submit two full programs.

Comment: Why not two lambdas?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You're not allowed to encode the answer in your choice of boolean flags, and IMHO allowing lambdas would violate that loophole, but for named functions the answer isn't encoded in the name, so that's OK. (You could of course just pay the penalty for naming your lambdas.)

Comment: Some languages don't feature named lambdas, e.g. a LISP dialect without `defvar`. It seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: What's wrong with lambdas? That rule is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

## Front lines go front! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

Given two lists of positive integers, bring the elements in the first one that are in the second to the far left, keeping their order the same as in the first list. You can assume that the second list's elements will all be unique.

[These approaches](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024) are forbidden.

For example, let's call the first list \$A\$ and the second \$B\$. Here are some test cases:

\$A=[1,3,4,1,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,4,1],B=[1,3]\rightarrow[1,3,1,1,3,1,3,1,4,2,4,2,2,4]\$

\$A=[],B=[1,4,5]\rightarrow[]\$

\$A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10],B=[]\rightarrow[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]\$

\$A=[],B=[]\rightarrow[]\$

\$A=[1,2,2,1,3,4,4],B=[1,2]\rightarrow[1,2,2,1,3,4,4]\$

\$A=[3,4,4,1,2,1,5],B=[1,5,2]\rightarrow[1,2,1,5,3,4,4]\$

\$A=[1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1],B=[4,5,6]\rightarrow[1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1]\$

\$A=[2,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,4],B=[1,2,3,4]\rightarrow[2,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,4]\$

Note: the integers aren't necessarily single-digit.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes. How could it be used anyway?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

## Radiation Showdown KotH

In radiation hardening challenges, the goal is to write a program whose behavior doesn't change when an arbitrary character is removed from its source.  This KotH explores an adversarial variant on this challenge in which two programs compete to survive the most character deletions.  The twist is that each program is provided the source code of its opponent and outputs which character should be deleted from its opponent's source code next.

### Gameplay

Suppose program A and B are competitors.

1. Each program is run and the output is recorded.  Let the output of program A be a and the output of program B be b.  If one program fails to output a valid character index of its opponent's source code, the other program will be declared the winner of the match.  If neither program outputs a valid index, then a tie is declared.
2. The a'th character is removed from program B and the b'th character is removed from program A.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until there is a winner or a tie.

### Submissions

Submissions should be a complete javascript or python program which:

- Begins with a shebang (#!) indicating which language it is written.  For python entries, this should be `#!/usr/bin/python`.  For javascript entries this should be `#!/app/.heroku/node/bin/node`.
- Takes three command line arguments: the code for the opponent program, the start of the range of deletable characters (x), and the end of the range (y).  In python these can be accessed using sys.argv, while in javascript they can be found in process.argv.
- Prints a number in the range [x,y) to stdout and terminates in less than 10 seconds.

Note: The index of the first deletable character of your opponent's program (x) is the index of the first character after the shebang.  y is the length of the opponent program in characters (so y-1 is the last deletable character).

### Sample Submissions

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
print (sys.argv[3]-1)
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

Javascript:

```
#!/app/.heroku/node/bin/node
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
console.log(Math.round(Math.random() * process.argv[4]));
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

### Controller

I've hosted a web based controller at https://radiationshowdownkoth.herokuapp.com/.  It should conform to the behavior specified in the Gameplay section.  Let me know if you find any bugs.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- The use of preexisting interpreters and their components (parsers, lexers, etc) is banned.  This includes, but is not limited to, calling the python and node binaries from your program (eg os.popen("python -c ...")), using builtin eval functions (eg python's exec), and using relevant modules (such as python's astlib).  However, you may use regular expressions.
- No malicious code.

### Logistics

It will be a Round Robin Tournament.  Each submission will be matched against every other submission.  For each victory a submission achieves, it will be awarded 1 point.  Likewise, ties are worth 0.5 points and losses are worth 0 points.  The submission with the most points after all rounds have been completed wins this KotH.  The winner will receive a bounty from yours truly, and the most popular entry will be awarded accepted answer.  This KotH will be open to entries for a week following its posting, at which point the tournament will be run and a winner declared.

### Meta

- Duplicate?
- Clarifications?
- Other Language Suggestions besides Python & Javascript?
- Are there any trivial strategies that would be overwhelmingly effective?
- Any other foreseeable problems?

Comment: Would an empty program that outputs 0 auto win?

Comment: Also, removing the shebang would kill the program.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, I believe an empty program that outputs 0 would always win as the rules are currently written.  Is it possible to write such a program in Javascript or Python?

Comment: @user202729 Actually, I am mistaken.  If a program outputs 0 it will lose because 0 is not in the valid range of deletable characters (passed in as the second and third arguments to the program).  This range starts after the end of the shebang in order to prevent the second exploit you pointed out.  I will try to clarify this in the spec.  However, a 0 character program that printed its second command line argument would auto win.  As far as I know, it is not possible to write such a program in Javascript or Python, but please let me know how if it is.  Thanks for the exploits :).

Comment: How are x and y computed?

Comment: @user202729 x is the index of the first character after the shebang.  y is the length of the program in bytes.  I've edited the spec to include this information.

Comment: I like it! I'm not very experienced, but I'd say it's ready to go.

Comment: Hm... in that case I'd say that because Python and Javascript are both "sensitive" (?) to radiation, making a program that would never lose is pretty easy. (just remove the first non-comment character or similar)

Comment: @user202729 One way to defend yourself against a program that deletes the first non-comment character would be to define a variable with a really long name on the first non-comment line of the program.  But I see your point.  Any ideas for better choices of languages?

Comment: It might be better to make the challenge "given a Python/JS program, delete a character so that it throws an error." Because AFAIK it's always possible, and such a program will never lose.

Answer (score 1):

## "Cumbersome Crown words"

## Introduction

This is my first entry here, so please be gentle if it's poorly stated. I'll need a bit of guidance to make it a good submission.

I am a typewriter maker, and I want to prove that the design of my competitor, Mr. Crown, is very inconvenient to use. To do that, I want a list of the most cumbersome words to type out on a [Crown typewriter](https://hardmath123.github.io/crown-typewriter.html).

## Challenge

Write a program that takes an argument "n" as a positive integer. You may load the [Unix words list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)) from any source (ignore case; discard any word containing anything outside of A-Z, such as "O'Brien", "L'vov", etc.). Given the layout shown below, output the "n" most cumbersome words to write, one result per line. Each result is the cumbersome word, some form of separator (eg. a space), then their word score (see below) with two decimals of precision (and your choice of decimal separator). Bonus if results are sorted in descending order by their word score, and further bonus if ties (by score) are also sorted in alphabetic order.

[image: Crown typewriter layout]

> X Q K G B P M C O F L A N D T H E R I S U W Y J V Z

## Word scoring

Assume the pointer starts in the leftmost position, on "X". Count each movement and each hammer strike as one unit, but divide the sum by the number of characters in the word. Hence, sample word scores are:

- **THEIR: 4.8** -- 24 units (14 movements, strike "T", movement, strike "H", movement, strike "E", 2 movements, strike "I", movement, strike "R") divided by 5 characters
- **LAND: 4.25** -- 17 units (10 movements, strike "L", movement, strike "A", movement, strike "N", movement, strike "D") divided by 4 characters
- **FOWL: 9.50** -- 38 units (9 movements, strike "F", movement, strike "O", 13 movements, strike "W", 11 movements, strike "L") divided by 4 characters
- **BARBARA : 8.00** -- 56 units (4 movements, strike "B", 7 movements, strike "A", 6 movements, strike "R", 13 movements, strike "B", 7 movements, strike "A", 6 movements, strike "R", 6 movements, strike "A") divided by 7 characters
- **X: 1** -- just hit the hammer once and you're done

**Note:** These examples are not the most cumbersome words.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 5

Standard output:

> ANNA 4.25
>
> THEIR 4.80
>
> LAND 4.25
>
> BARBARA 8.00
>
> FOWL 9.50

Bonus output:

> FOWL 9.50
>
> BARBARA 8.00
>
> THEIR 4.80
>
> ANNA 4.25
>
> LAND 4.25

## Scoring submissions and determining the winner

I'm really not sure what the best measure of success is. Definitely not code golf, because I can never distinguish the damn things from line noise or pure black magic. But what then? I'm not very familiar with which competition types are available.

If two solutions are tied for a position, but only one of them uses the bonus output format, then that one wins the tie.

Comment: Tak for at du bruger sandkassen!

Comment: You can find a list of all winning criteria [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/56433), though I think [tag:code-golf] is actually the best fit. When you are bothered by illegible answers, try asking for an explanation, most users are happy to explain how their code works and which tricks they used.

Comment: As for the challenge, it would be helpful to provide a transcript of the order of the letters from the image. I personally like challenges to focus on their core, in this case calculating the score of a word, and to avoid additional tasks, like sorting a list and printing the top `n` entries, as those can distract from the main challenge. (E.g. in a language without a build-in sort method the challenging part could become implementing a sorting algorithm even though that's presumably not the intention of your challenge.)

Comment: @Laikoni thank you for the reference! I am leaning towards [popularity-contest], but otherwise I guess I can settle for [code-golf].

Comment: [tag:popularity-contest] challenges are very hard to get right, read e.g. [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8134/56433). I'd strongly advise you against using it, as it is not a good fit for this otherwise nice challenge.

Comment: Is the word list common for all solutions or may the answerer choose their word list?

Comment: I can restrict it to the [Unix Words file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)) if that helps.

Comment: If not a [popularity-contest], then what's the best way to score this, given that I desire code readability (so not [code-golf])?

Comment: Imo, the heart of the challenge is to determine the score of a word: I consider the rest as unnecessary, reading words from files has been done and will only make it difficult (or even impossible) for some languages, sorting with a custom function too, has been done. So I would extract the heart of this challenge and state it as *Given a word, output its score*.

Comment: Now, since you don't want a [tag:code-golf], [tag:popularity-contest] is not really the right thing, the challenge is not computationally hard (ruling out [tag:fastest-code] or the like) that kind of leaves us with: [tag:atomic-code-golf] or [tag:code-challenge]. For the former one I don't see a sensible way to define the challenge which leaves us with the latter and gives rise to a start of a really interesting challenge: Make it a [tag:code-challenge] where the scoring is according to the word's score ("*cumbersome-ness*"). The problem will be characters outside of that range:

Comment: **Ideas** (for all I'm assuming case-insensitivity): 1) You extend the range to include `@!…⅓` and exchange the character `_` or the unreadable one after `Z` with a space. Then you'll only allow submissions using this extended range. [imo the most sensible, it does restrict the submissions heavily but in an interesting and sensible way so] 2) Before scoring the submission, remove all characters outside of the range. [people will abuse this and only use characters outside of that range] 3) Only `XQ…Z` are valid in a submission. [this is a really tight restriction for most languages]

Comment: 4) Instead of ignoring characters outside that range, penalize them with a constant (kind of expensive, but not too expensive).

Comment: @BMO, thanks a ton for your feedback! I'm not sure I follow (= I'm pretty sure I *don't* follow) your "ideas" comment. Could you explain further?

Comment: If you go the route of [tag:code-challenge] with score being the "*cumbersomeness*" of the code itself, it's not clear how you'll treat characters which aren't in the range `XQ…Z` and there would be need of a way to score these. The ideas (1-4) would be different options to define that.

Answer (score 1):

## Where can I get to from each location? (Transitive Closure)

Given an undirected [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) (network) \$G\$, construct a new graph in which vertex (node) pair \$(u,v)\$ is an edge (are connected) if and only if a path \$(u,w_1,w_2,...,w_k,v)\$ exists in \$G\$ for some \$k\ge 0\$. This is known as \$G\$'s transitive closure. If this is clear to you, you're ready to get started. Otherwise, just read through the below sections. It is actually a very simple problem.

### I/O formats

Take for example the graph (network)

```
1──2  3──4
│     │
5  6──7──8
```

We can represent¹ it as an adjacency (connection) matrix:

```
 │1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
─┼───────────────
1│  ┘ 
2│
3│      ┘
4│
5│┘
6│            ┘
7│    ┘         ┘
8│
```

which is:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Note that here only one of \$(u,v),(v,u)\$ is represented, but we consider both directions as valid edges (connections).

Or as a list of of edges²:

```
[[1,2],[1,5],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8]]
```

Or for each vertex³ (node), the list of its adjacent vertices:

```
[[2,5],[1],[7,4],[1],[7],[3,8],[8],[]]
```

Or as a dictionary⁴:

```
{"1":[2,5],"3":[7,4],"7":[6,3,8]}
```

Any of these, and any other reasonable input and output formats (you optionally may use one format for input and another for output) are allowed, but you must state what your formats are.
 However, it *is* required that your formats support under-representing (e.g. `[3,7]` *but not* `[7,3]`) and over-representing (e.g. both `[3,7]` *and* `[7,3]`).

### Walk-through

Let's use the representation `[[1,2],[1,5],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8]]`. Since 1 is connected to 2 then 2 is also connected to 1, so we add (it doesn't matter where) this edge (connection):

`[[1,2],[1,5],[2,1],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8]]`

It is also possible to travel `[1,5]` in reverse, but that pair is already represented further in the list. Now note that it is possible to find a path from 2 to 5, and vice versa, via 1, so we add these two edges:

`[[1,2],[1,5],[2,1],[2,5],[5,2],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8]]`

This completes the left side of the graph. Similarly, we process the right side by adding the reversals of `[3,4]`, `[6,7]`, and `[7,3]`:

`[[1,2],[1,5],[2,1],[2,5],[5,2],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8],[4,3],[7,6],[7,3]]`

Two-step paths via 3 are possible, so we add `[7,4]` and `[4,7]`. Similarly, two-step paths via 7 are `[6,3]`, `[3,6]`, `[6,8]`, `[8,6]`, `[3,8]`, and `[8,3]`:

`[[1,2],[1,5],[2,1],[2,5],[5,2],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8],[4,3],[7,6],[7,3],[7,4],[4,7],[6,3],[3,6],[6,8],[8,6],[3,8],[8,3]]`

Finally, we add the three-step paths `[6,4]`, `[4,6]`, `[4,8]`, and `[8,4]`:

`[[1,2],[1,5],[2,1],[2,5],[5,2],[3,4],[5,1],[6,7],[7,3],[7,8],[4,3],[7,6],[7,3],[7,4],[4,7],[6,3],[3,6],[6,8],[8,6],[3,8],[8,3],[6,4],[4,6],[4,8],[8,4]]`

And this is our answer. It could of course be in any order.

---

1. <sup>Though the connections do not have direction, I've only put in one entry in the table for each connection, and obviously the diagonal is all-true too, as every node is reachable from itself.</sup>
2. <sup>Since the connections in this challenge do not have a direction, `[1,5]` and `[5,1]` are the same connection. This serves to illustrate that such may occur in the given data.</sup>
3. <sup>Here, each node must have its own list, as the lists are paired to their points by their position in the data. However, each list need not be exhaustive as long as all connections are represented somewhere.</sup>
4. <sup>Here, we can omit entries that are fully covered by the other entries.</sup>

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

Comment: Am I over complicating things by allowing all the various I/Os?

Comment: All the input formats you mentioned seem reasonable to me and I'm sure different languages could use different formats when golfing. And if you restrict it to one specific format, you'll get people asking about using other formats anyways.

Comment: why not state it in graph-theoretic terms - _vertex_, _edge_, _path_, _graph_, _incidence matrix_ - instead of the more vague _location/place/point_, _connection_, _journey_, _network_, _connection table_? "[1,5] and [5,1] are _of course_ the same connection" - it would be just as valid and interesting a problem if it were about directed graphs, so it's not "of course" :) tag "repeated-transformation" is unnecessary - this can be solved in O(n^3) time without the use of `⍣≡`.

Comment: @Emigna Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @ngn Reason: I am not educated enough. Can I bother you to edit those in? I'll remove "of course".

Comment: @Adám sure, i'll edit it. it's nice you put "transitive closure" in the title. many challenge authors (with or without cs/maths degrees) like to reinvent terminology, obscure the problem with backstories, etc. i find that mildly annoying. [example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48267420#48267420) - seems to be an interesting challenge but it takes so long to figure out what the words mean.

Comment: @Adám how does it sound now? i'm not sure if i didn't go to far with that pseudo-academic lingo...

Comment: @ngn Thank you so much. I've added in parenthesised layman's terms upon first usage in each section, and added a bit to the intro to keep people from fleeing. I also inserted the word "pair" on the very first line before (*u*,*v*) as it seemed to me that it was missing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Adám i forgot to delete the word "vertex". inserting "pair" should be fine too

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/158239/194). [Directed version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76299/194).

Answer (score 1):

## Unfactor a list [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jelly) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

[Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage) has an interesting built-in, `ÆẸ`. It's the inverse of `ÆE`. `ÆE` returns the exponents of the prime factors of an integer `n`, where each exponent corresponds to the prime number at its index, so, for example, `[3, 5, 1]` represents \$2^3\cdot3^5\cdot5^1\$. If a prime isn't included in the prime factorization of `n`, but there is at least one prime after it that is included, a zero is put in its place (\$p^0=1\$). So, for example, `[3, 0, 5, 1]` represents \$2^3\cdot5^5\cdot7^1\$, and `[0, 4, 4, 50, 0, 7]` represents \$3^4\cdot5^4\cdot7^{50}\cdot13^7\$.

Your job is to implement `ÆẸ`, `ÆE`'s inverse. That is, you'll be given a list returned by `ÆE`, and your job is to find `n`.

You must always return a positive integer (strictly greater than zero). You may assume the input doesn't have negative or float exponents or trailing zeroes.

Note that you're encouraged not to use `ÆẸ` or your language's equivalent (if any) in your answer.

Using any of the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024) is prohibited.

Test cases (you don't have to support exponents, an output or an input's length beyond your natural signed integer type's limit):

```
[] -> 1
[0, 4] -> 81
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] -> 1111
[10] -> 1024
[3, 5, 1] -> 9720
[3, 0, 5, 1] -> 175000
[31] -> 2147483648
[32] -> 4294967296
[63] -> 9223372036854775808
[64] -> 18446744073709551616
[0, 4, 4, 50, 0, 7] -> 5713082599062385095715588395684396863698753591853983125
```

Make more test cases:

To generate the input that corresponds to a given output, use [this program](https://tio.run/##DchBEYAwEANAS21DrokApPBhagADCOCFFd4MQlBysM9dlzG2zHufn@O9zsxkryhqtEs0iMX/kBLM0ASHAmF1gq4iLNTGDw).

To generate the output that corresponds to a given input, use [this program](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28NdO/7//x9toKNgAkamQBYQmccCAA).

Comment: @Adám Hm, I included the stuff for clarity, but I can remove it as well. EDIT: Removed the fluff.

Answer (score 1):

## My Number is Bigger Than Yours: KoTH

The concept of this game is simple; each turn, two bots submit a positive integer (in Python, so no upper bound on its size). Whichever bot submits a larger number wins a certain number of points based on the scoring put forward in the next section. This process is iterated a certain number (100?) times to form the competition, with the bot which has the highest score winning the competition between the two bots.

**However**, scoring is based on some metric of the difference between the submitted values such that the larger the difference is, the smaller the amount of score gained is. I'm trying to decide some metric which heavily incentivizes making a guess which narrowly beats your opponent's guess, maybe with a metric such as `1/(a-b)**2`. However, as the numbers will likely grow throughout the iterations, maybe `1/(a/b)**2` might be better.

Example bot whose goal is to beat opponents who pick a constant number:

```
def constant_beater(my_score, opp_score, my_numbers, opp_numbers):
    if len(opp_numbers) == 0:
        return 1
    return opp_numbers[-1] + 1
```

The largest concern I see with this challenge is a bot which just increments much quicker than all other bots so that it wins every game with a minuscule amount every time. Maybe to curb this a score that is below a certain threshold for a game is rounded to zero to encourage more competitive choices.

Comment: I feel like this would be a much better challenge if bounded a bit, from maybe 1-100 for example

Comment: I was thinking of some sort of bounding, but I'm struggling to then find an incentive for a bot to choose anything except for the upper bound.

Comment: Make it a round robin tournament?

Comment: Numbers from 1 to 100. 100 rounds between 2 bots, higher number wins, can only play each of the 100 numbers 1 time each. Score is the number of rounds won? The play method doesn't work well for difference between numbers.

Comment: This sounds extremely abusable, even more if they try to tap into the others' functions. However, it still sounds real fun, reminds me of the [Robot Roulette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173209/robot-roulette-high-stakes-robot-gambling) but with much better winning chances.

Maybe you could add some restriction like preventing to use the same number X amount of rounds with a maximum number cap (like @fəˈnɛtɪk said but without too much limiting)

Comment: Maybe instead of a maximum number cap a maximum sum cap?

Comment: If there's a maximum number cap I don't think there needs to be a maximum sum cap. However, there needs to be an incentive so bots don't go spamming the maximum number 24/7 (or worse, having 2 bots spam max number to infinity and ending in a 0 point tie)

Comment: Thinking about this:  Perhaps the max is 100, and bots score 100-guess if they win, and -(guess/100) if they lose?

Answer (score 1):

## **A Turtle Finds a Portal**

The turtle wants to move along the grid to get to his food. He wants to know how many moves it will take for him to get there.

As well since he is slow he has teleporters set up around his domain that he will utilize if it shortens his path. Or avoid them if it lengthens his path.

### *Meet the turtle*

The turtle lives on a grid
$$\begin{matrix}
X&X&X&X&X\\
X&X&X&X&X\\
X&X&&X&X\\
X&X&X&X&X\\
X&X&X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$
The turtle can move to any adjacent square...
$$\begin{matrix}
X&X&X&X&X\\
X&\nwarrow&\uparrow&\nearrow&X\\
X&\leftarrow&&\rightarrow&X\\
X&\swarrow&\downarrow&\searrow&X\\
X&X&X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$

However, the turtle cannot move to a square with a mountain
$$\begin{matrix}
X&&X&X&X\\
X&\nwarrow&\uparrow&\nearrow&X\\
X&&&\rightarrow&X\\
X&&\downarrow&\searrow&X\\
X&&X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$

The turtle wants to eat his straw berry, and would like to know how long it will take to get to his strawberry
$$\begin{matrix}
X&&\\
&&X\\
X&&X\\
X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$
This example would take the turtle \$5\$ turns
$$\begin{matrix}
X&&\\
\downarrow&&\uparrow\\
\searrow&&\uparrow\\
X&\nearrow&X\\
\end{matrix}$$
To get around mountains the turtle uses his teleporter. There are two teleports on the grid that map to each other. Stepping on the teleporter immediately moves the turtle to the corresponding teleporter.
$$\begin{matrix}
&&\\
&&\\
X&&X\\
X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$
It is now faster for the turtle to move up twice. Now the turtles shortest path is \$2\$
$$\begin{matrix}
&&\\
\uparrow&&\uparrow\\
X&&X\\
X&X&X\\
\end{matrix}$$

### The challenge

Given an initial grid configuration output the number of moves it will take the turtle to reach his strawberry.

### Rules

- You may assume that the input grid has a solution
- The input grid may be entered in any convenient format
- The shortest path does not need to make use of the portal
- The turtle cannot pass into mountain tiles
- The turn that the turtle moves onto a teleporter square he is already on the corresponding teleporter. He never moves onto a teleporter and stays there for a move
- You may use any ASCII character to represent `mountains`, `turtle`, `empty gird square`, `strawberry`.
- You may use either the same character or two different characters to represent the `teleporter` pairs
- A grid can have more than one path with the same shortest path length
- Each grid will only have one strawberry and two portals
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Test Cases formatted as lists

```
[ ['T', 'X', 'X', 'S', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'] ] --> 3
[ ['T', 'M', 'X', 'S', 'X'], ['X', 'M', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'] ] --> 4
[ ['T', 'M', 'X', 'S', 'O'], ['O', 'M', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'] ] --> 2
[ ['T', 'M', 'X', 'S', 'X'], ['O', 'M', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'] ] --> 4
[ ['T', 'M', 'S', 'X', 'O'], ['X', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O'] ] --> 7
```

### Test Cases formatted for humans

```
T X X S X
X X X X X
X X X X X --> 3

T M X S X
X M X X X
O X X X O --> 4

T M X S O
O M X X X
X X X X X --> 2

T M X S X
O M X X X
O X X X X --> 4

T M S X O
X M M M M
X X X X O --> 7
```

**Credits**

Design and structure via: [*Hungry mouse by Arnauld*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/176251/79844)

Proposed Challenges Edit Advice: [*Kamil-drakari*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71434/kamil-drakari), [*beefster*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45613/beefster)

Comment: How many teleporters at most?

Comment: @Quintec Since they say pairs, then... only two at most, because there's no way to represent multiple pairs

Comment: @Quintec. Yea one at most. I'll add to the rules.

Comment: You should clarify how diagonal moves work near mountains. The first diagram showing the basic movement options includes diagonal moves, but the example with the strawberry would only be two moves regardless of portals if a diagonal move was used.

Comment: @kmail. Very true. Will add condition when on computer.

Comment: I would suggest taking the "gun" out of the title because "portal gun" suggests being able to place your own portals. I would also allow input to be in any convenient format rather than requiring it to be a list of lists with a predefined key. I think for your examples, you should use space and newline separated grids. And one last thing: rather than "The grid must have a possible solution to reach the strawberry", you should state "You may assume that the input grid has a solution". Good challenge though. Just a couple tweaks will make it a *great* challenge.

Comment: I would like a testcase where the portal is in the way of the turtle, meaning that the turtle has to use the portal twice. Something like `"TOSMO","MMMMX", "XXXXX"` or `"TOSXX", "MMMMX", "OXXXX"` (both evaluate to 4 moves)

Comment: @BlackOwlKai I'm considering making portals single use? Thoughts?

Comment: This is also an option and could allow some more interesting golf approaches. Also, the single-use option would make brute-force algorithms more lengthy, because they need to keep track of whether the portal has been used. Either way, it should be clarified in the rules. But I still would like to add a testcase `"XXXMO", "XMXMX", "XOXMX", TMSMX"`, where the portal is between the turtle and the strawberry, even if portals are single-use.

Comment: Will do. I'll add this to rules aftter I get off my bus ride. As I won't have internet to edit. Cheers, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Support for the emoticons is not guaranteed, and they aren't in the fonts on my Linux system. IMO an image would be preferable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Will do. I'll do this once home from work. If you want to try doing it now I would approve the edit. Cheers.

Comment: You have a typo on rule 6: "empty gird square" should be "empty grid square". Also, why does it need to be an ASCII character value? Why can't I use an int?

Comment: Will fix the spelling. As far as I'm aware integers [are ascii characters?](https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html)

Comment: @Beefster I'll specify in the post though.

Comment: @Beefster added "ASCII character or integer" to valid input names

Answer (score 1):

## Drawing \$K_n\$ (complete graph with \$n\$ vertices)

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

---

In graph theory the complete graph with \$n\$ vertices, often written as \$K_n\$, is the graph where every vertex is connected to every other vertex. For example, \$K_3\$ with \$V = \{A,B,C\}\$ has the edges \$\bigr\{\{A,B\},\{B,C\},\{C,A\}\bigl\}\$ - forming a triangle.

### Challenge

Given an **even** \$n \geq 4\$ you will generate/display an image of the graph \$K_n\$ as follows:

- pick an image width \$\texttt{width} \geq 100\$
- pick two distinct colors \$\texttt{vertex_color}\$ and \$\texttt{edge_color}\$
- draw \$1\$ vertex with color \$\texttt{vertex_color}\$ in the middle of the image
- draw the remaining \$n-1\$ vertices evenly distributed on a circle around it
- connect every vertex with color \$\texttt{edge_color}\$

### Rules

- the background color doesn't matter (transparent is fine), but it must not coincide with the colors \$\texttt{vertex_color}\$ and \$\texttt{edge_color}\$
- the radius of the circle should be \$\texttt{width/4}\$
- the center of the circle should the middle of the image
- the shape of the vertices doesn't matter, but they must be at least \$3\$ pixels wide
- the edges must not overlap the vertices
- the edges may be dashed, dotted etc.

### Examples

#### Example output for \$K_4\$:

[image: K_4]

#### Example output for \$K_{12}\$:

[image: K_12]

#### Example output for \$K_{32}\$:

[image: K_32]

Comment: "*the edges must not overlap the vertices*" is incompatible with "*draw 1 vertex ... in the middle of the image*" when n is odd.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Good call, thank you! Restricted the input to only even integers.

Comment: a bit too many rules for me but... still very interesting and fun

Comment: @donbright: What do you mean by too many rules? Since it's graphical output, I have to set rules otherwise it'll become an art contest unfortunately. I'm open to less restrictive suggestions though.

Comment: its just my personal taste. like i dont care how wide the image is, how wide vertices are or whether edges overlap, etc etc. i upvoted anyways. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

## Chain round the number!

A decimal place is a digit of a number's location in a number. In the number `987654321`, each digit corresponds to its decimal place. For example, in the number `16111`, the `6` is in the 4th decimal place.

Normally when rounding to `n` decimal places, one checks the digit at `n-1` (heretofore called `x`). If `x >= 5`, then the digit at `n` is rounded up. Otherwise the digit at `n` is rounded down (stays the same). Then, all digits including and after `x` are turned into 0.

For example, take the number `158`, rounded to the 3rd decimal place. The digit at the 2nd decimal place (3rd decimal place minus one) is 5. Because of this, the `1` at the third decimal place gets rounded up. This results in the number being `258`. However, the `5` and the `8` both get turned into `0`, and so the final result is `200`.

Chain rounding is like normal rounding, except that you do it to every digit starting with the digit at decimal place 2. Once you round to the decimal place 2, then you round to decimal place 3, and so on until decimal place n.

For example:

```
Input: 24472
24472    (2 < 5, so the 7 rounds down)
24470    (7 >= 5, so the 4 rounds up)
24500    (5 >= 5, so the 4 rounds up)
25000    (5 >= 5, so the 2 rounds up)
30000    (Final answer. Non chain-rounded answer would be 20000)
```

The challenge here is to chain round a number to the highest decimal place possible for that number.

**Test cases:** (all inputs will be positive whole numbers)

```
24472 -> 30000
1999 -> 2000    ("1 9 9 9" -> "1 9 10 0" -> "1 10 0 0" -> "2 0 0 0")
9945 -> 10000
2001 -> 2000
9444 -> 9000
9445 -> 10000
13579 -> 10000
24681 -> 30000
1337 -> 1000
5 -> 10
1 -> 1
```

Comment: Good challenge, but I think this needs more explanation on what is happening. It's probably a good idea to fix an example with digits \$ab\$ and explain how the new rounding works (ie. compare \$b\$ to \$5\$ and so on), at first I did not understand where the \$5\$ comes from. You should also address how carries are treated, it's not clear atm.

Comment: @BMO I tried to clarify, is that better? (Thank you for the help).

Comment: Yes, looks good to me. Make sure to make a test-case with carries, eg. when rounding \$9996\$ or the like. And also specify whether numbers can be zero or even negative.

Answer (score 1):

[Playing Pickomino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179588/playing-picomino)

Comment: A worked example or 2 would be useful; I missed, on my first readthrough, that we must take the *highest* available tile `<=` the score rather than *any* tile `<=` the score and was therefore confused by a couple of the test cases. Although, I'm still confused by the 3rd last one - either the output is wrong or (more likely!) I'm too tired/drunk to figure it out. Nice challenge, though :)

Answer (score 1):

## SLIPpery Packets

The [Serial Line Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) is an early internet protocol, used to essentially escape any "packet END" bytes that may appear in a packet. It has since been replaced by the more sophisticated Point-to-Point protocol, however it is still preferred on microcontrollers and low-level devices due to its simplicity.

Your goal is to implement simplified encoding and decoding functions following this protocol as a function/program/subroutine/etc.

The following table lists the special bytes used:

```
Hex    Dec   ISO 8859-1   Abbrev  
0xC0   192   À            END      
0XDB   219   Û            ESC
0xDC   220   Ü            ESC_END
0xDD   221   Ý            ESC_ESC
```

(The ISO 8859-1 characters are for visualizing where non-ASCII bytes are in the string.)

Encoding follows this system, iterating through each byte:

- If the END byte appears in the packet, write ESC, ESC_END instead
- If the ESC byte appears in the packet, write ESC, ESC_ESC instead
- Otherwise, write byte verbatim
- At the end, an END byte is appended to the message, and it is returned

Some implementations, such as the reference C implementation from [RFC 1055](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1055), prepend an END byte to the string to be sent. This is omitted here for simplicity.

Decoding follows in reverse:

- If ESC, ESC_END appears in the packet, write END instead
- If ESC, ESC_ESC appears in the packet, write ESC instead
- Protocol violations that involve ESC followed by a "bad byte" that isn't ESC_END or ESC_ESC should be handled by writing the "bad byte"
- The first END byte seen (not following ESC) is interpreted as the end of the packet. The decoded packet should be returned without the END byte. You are guaranteed to have at least one such END byte appear.

### Input/Output

For encoding, input is a packet (string of bytes) and output is the encoded packet (string of bytes).

For decoding, input is a "byte stream" (string of bytes) and output is the (first) decoded packet (string of bytes).

### Test cases

**Inputs**

```
''                --> 'À'
'test\n'          --> 'test\nÀ'
'testÀ'           --> 'testÛÜÀ'
'teÛst'           --> 'teÛÝstÀ'
'À'               --> 'ÛÜÀ'
'ÛÜÛÝÀÛ'          --> 'ÛÝÜÛÝÝÛÜÛÝÀ'
```

**Outputs**

```
'À'               --> ''
'testÀblah blahÀ' --> 'test'
'teÛÝstÀ'         --> 'teÛst'
'testÛÜÛÜÀ'       --> 'testÀÀ'
'ÛÝÜÛÝÝÛÜÛÝÀ'     --> 'ÛÜÛÝÀÛ'
'ÛÀÀ'             --> 'À'
'ÛµÀ¶'            --> 'µ'
```

### Scoring

Your score is the sum of the number of bytes in your encoding and decoding functions (or programs, etc.)

---

I have also considered requiring functions to take a length of packet in bytes which is used in encoding and decoding (similar to RFC 1055), not requiring handling protocol violations (ex. RFC 1055), and not testing decoding packets that have an END byte as not the last byte. Your opinions on how restrictive this challenge should be are appreciated.

Comment: regex would not be too hard actually.

Answer (score 1):

## Gregorian-Hijri(Islamic) Calendar Conversion [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)

### Introduction

The [Hijri, or Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) is a lunar calendar used in the Islamic countries to determine the dates of traditional events. The year in the Hijri calendar is usually denoted **AH xxxx**. The Hijri calendar has an epoch on 16 July 622 on Julian calendar.

Like other lunar calendars, in the Hijri calendar a year consists of 12 months, each month consists of 29 or 30 days. A year is thus 354 days, or in leap years there are 355. On average there are 11 leap years every 30 years.

There is a [tabular variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Islamic_calendar) which uses arithmetic calculations in place of astronomical observations to determine the dates. There is also a [solar version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar) of the Hijri calendar, which is used in Iran and Afghanistan.

In this challenge, only the tabular variant will be discussed.

### The tabular Hijri calendar

*All western dates below will be shown in (possibly proleptic) Gregorian even if the date is before 15 October 1582.*

There are 12 months in each year in the Hijri calendar, with alternating 29- or 30-day periods. The odd months have 30 days, and the even months have 29 days (except for the 12th month *Dhu al-Hijjah* in leap years which also has 30 days). The month names are as follows (according to this [Wikipedia template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Muslimmonths)):

```
#    Name              Number of days
1    Muharram          30
2    Safar             29
3    Rabi' al-awwal    30
4    Rabi' al-Thani    29
5    Jumada al-awwal   30
6    Jumada al-Thani   29
7    Rajab             30
8    Sha'ban           29
9    Ramadan           30
10   Shawwal           29
11   Dhu al-Qidah      30
12   Dhu al-Hijjah     29 / 30 (in leap years only)
```

There are 11 leap years every 30 years. There are 3 versions to determine the leap years, but the most common version is to set the years with \$y\in\{2,5,7,10,13,16,18,21,24,26,29\}(\text{mod }30)\$ as leap years. (Be reminded that the calendar stars from year 1.)

The Hijri calendar has its first day (i.e. 1 *Muharram* 1) on 19 July 622.

As an example, we now convert the date 8 February 2019 into Hijri (Here we define a cycle to be 30 years):

1. Date: 8 February 2019
2. Dates from the Epoch: \$1396 \times 365 + 339 + 166 + 38 = 510083\$

   - There are 1396 (\$2019 - 623\$)  full years, so \$1396 \times 365\$ days
   - There are 339 (\$349 - 14 + 4\$) leap years between 2 dates
   - There are 166 days between 19 June 622 to 1 January 623, and 38 days between 1 January 2019 to 8 February 2019
3. Cycle: \$510083 \div 10631 = 47\text{ (cycles) and }10426\text{ (days)}\$

   - One ordinary year is 354 days and there are 11 leap years in a 30-year cycle, so total days in a cycle is \$354\frac{11}{30} \times 30 = 10631\$
4. \$10427 - (354 \times 29 + 11) = 150\$, so this this is the 150th day of the 30th year in the 48th cycle, which is \$47 \times 30 + 30 = \text{(AH) }1440\$.

   - The subtraction has 18 \$354\$s and 11 \$355\$s, but there is not enough space to write it all.
5. \$150 - 30 - 29 - 30 - 29 - 30 = 2\$, so this is the 2nd day of the 6th month in the year AH 1440.

As a result the complete Hijri date of 8 February 2019 is 2 *Jumada al-Thani* 1440.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that converts the (Gregorian) input date into the corresponding Hijri date.

The program or function may receive the input date in any reasonable format, but it must output the Hijri date in the format of `[date] [month name] [year]`. The italics above shall be ignored.

The input month and day may be 0-indexed for convenience, but you must state so if you use this convention.

You may assume that the input is always a valid Gregorian date, and is always not earlier than the Gregorian epoch of the calendar, 19 July 622.

### Sample I/O

```
Input:  "19 July 622" / "622-7-19" / [622, 7, 19] / (622, 6, 19) (0-indexed month)
Output: "1 Muharram 1" (The epoch date)

Input:  "8 February 2019" / "2019-2-8" / [2019, 2, 8] / (2019, 1, 8) (0-indexed month)
Output: "2 Jumada al-Thani 1440" (The example date)

Input:  "12 August 2019" / "2019-8-12" / [2019, 8, 12] / (2019, 7, 12) (0-indexed month)
Output: "10 Dhu al-Hijjah 1440" (The start date of Eid ul-Adha in AH 1440)

Input:  "9 August 2021" / "2021-8-9" / [2021, 8, 9] / (2021, 7, 9) (0-indexed month)
Output: "30 Dhu al-Hijjah 1442" (The next leap day)
```

### Winning Criteria

As this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer of each language wins. Standard loopholes are banned by default.

Comment: What is "47 R 10426"?

Comment: @Adám The quotient is 47, with remainder 10426. When I was in primary school I was taught like 5/3 = 1...2 and heard in western countries it'd be written as 5/3 = 1 R2

Comment: This starts off really well, explicitly addressing the usual ambiguities with Gregorian calendar-related questions and the particular complications of the Islamic calendar. But for me it starts to fall apart at the example, which has a lot of unexplained magic numbers and introduces new terms like *cycle*. I suggest that you should take the example slower: which number in step 2 is the number of leap days? Define a cycle as (I assume) 30 Iunar years.

Comment: I also suggest that you reconsider the requirement to output month names. That really makes it two barely related challenges (a calendar conversion and a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] for an array of 12 strings) packaged as one.

Answer (score 1):

## One circle, two inputs, eight outputs

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)
[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)
[pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)

Given the values of only two quantities from the following eight quantities ​​(the rest is unknown):

1. Radius of circle: \$\displaystyle R\$
2. Diameter of the circle: \$\displaystyle D=2\times R\$
3. Circumference of the sector: \$\displaystyle C=2\times\pi\times R=\pi\times D\$
4. Area of the circle: \$\displaystyle A=\pi\times R^2\$
5. Angle of the sector: \$\displaystyle\alpha\$
6. Length of arc: \$\displaystyle LA=\frac{C\times \alpha}{360°}\$
7. Area of the sector: \$\displaystyle AS=\frac{A\times \alpha}{360°}\$
8. Perimeter of the sector: \$\displaystyle PS=LA+2\times R=LA+D\$

compute the rest of quantities if possible, else put special output (-1, False,...) if at least one of the quantities can not be computed.

### Input

Two quantities with there values (non negative integers)

### Output

The values of the eight previous quantities (decimal with any precision or rounded integer).

### Example

In this example the inputs is the ordered list of the previous quantities. Values are integers, angles in degrees, and outputs as rounded integers.

```
[16, ?, ?, ?, 100, ?, ?, ?]   --> [16, 32, 100, 804, 100, 27, 223, 59]
[24, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 58]    --> [24, 48, 150, 1809, 23, 10, 120, 58]
[28, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 188]   --> [28, 56, 175, 2463, 270, 132, 1848, 188]
[?, 18, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 41]    --> [9, 18, 56, 254, 146, 23, 103, 41]
[?, 28, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 808]   --> [14, 28, 87, 615, 3191, 780, 5460, 808]
[?, 88, 220, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?]   --> False
[?, ?, 88, ?, ?, 84, ?, ?]    --> [14, 28, 88, 616, 343, 84, 588, 112]
[?, ?, 220, ?, ?, 66, ?, ?]   --> [35, 70, 220, 3851, 108, 66, 1155, 136]
[?, ?, ?, 50, 50, ?, ?, ?]    --> [3, 7, 25, 50, 50, 3, 6, 11]
[?, ?, ?, 254, ?, ?, 18, ?]   --> [8, 17, 56, 254, 25, 4, 18, 21]
[?, ?, ?, 707, 75, ?, ?, ?]   --> [15, 30, 94, 707, 75, 19, 147, 49]
[?, ?, ?, ?, 99, 24, ?, ?]    --> [13, 27, 87, 606, 99, 24, 166, 51]
[?, ?, ?, ?, 140, ?, 175, ?]  --> [11, 23, 75, 450, 140, 29, 175, 53]
[?, ?, ?, ?, 324, 85, ?, ?]   --> [15, 30, 94, 709, 324, 85, 638, 115]
[?, ?, ?, ?, 324, ?, 3465, ?] --> [35, 70, 219, 3850, 324, 197, 3465, 267]
[?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 66, 88, ?]    --> False
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Specify in the answer the special output when quantities can not be computed all.
- Specify in the answer whether the angle is in degree or radian or other unit.
- π can be set to 3.14 or 22/7 or 355/113 or any more precise value.
- No need to handle invalid input values.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Unique Skittle Pairs

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
This is my first question, so hopefully it's OK.

I like to eat Skittles. However, I only like to eat them in pairs, and and those pairs must not have two Skittles of the same color. Your task is to find the most pairs that you can that match these requirements.

## Challenge

Input (taken from standard input) is a set of Skittles formatted like so: `pyyyggoooorr`, where `p` is purple, `y` is yellow, `g` is green, `o` is orange, and `r` is red. The number of letters for each color corresponds to the number of Skittles that are that color. The only colors used in this challenge are purple, yellow, green, orange, and red. The input will always be even in length and lowercase.

Output is the most possible pairs of Skittles that I like to eat given the input. Different outputs don't matter as long as they are valid, i.e. for an input of `pygo`, both `py go` and `po gy` are valid outputs. Output for invalid input doesn't matter.

The output must be in the same format as the test cases.

## Examples/Test Cases

Permutations of these solutions are valid. You do not have to output all valid outputs. Multiple output lines here means multiple valid outputs.

```
> ppyy
py py

> yggooo
yo go go

> pyygorrr
pr yr yg or
py yr gr or

> yggoor
yg go or
yo go gr
go go yr

> yggor
(anything, including no output/errors)

> gygoro
yg go or
yo go gr
go go yr

> ygoOor
(anything, including no output/errors)

> ggorrrrr
gr gr or

> pppyyygggooorrrr
py py py ro ro ro rg
po po po ry ry ry rg
py po py ro ry ro rg
etc.
```

Least bytes wins.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: I believe this is a [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59192/31625). The only differences are the slightly more inconvenient input/output of this challenge and the different group size. However, forcing the output to be the actual pairs prevents using the most dominant strategy of simply calculating the number of groups. Personally I think they are too close anyway, but some people may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

## Sort according to cyclic order

[Cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) on a set is a function f taking three distinct elements of a set, returning bool and having following properties:

1. If f(a, b, c) then f(b, c, a)
2. If f(a, b, c) then not f(c, b, a)
3. If f(a, b, c) and f(a, c, d) then f(a, b, d)
4. One of f(a, b, c) and f(c, b, a) is true

Values of f when arguments are not distinct don't matter.
You are given a list of dictinct numbers and a function f posessing the above properties when arguments are taken from the list. Your task is to arrange the numbers in such an odrer that

f(a, b, c) if and only if k > j > i or i > k > j or j > i > k

(i.e. numbers a, b, c come in that order modulo cyclic permutaion)

Score is the total number of calls to the function f on some dataset.

It's not very clear to me how to create the dataset and how to count calls to f across different languages. Is it better to just give a list of n*(n-1)*(n-2) values of f as input (and score by bytes)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG. Thank you for using the Sandbox. Please don't specify a challenge using a specific (and unstated) programming language, as many people will have a hard time understanding that. At the very least, explain the notation.

Comment: @Adám Thank you for your comment. I've removed all language-specific notation

Comment: Is 4. OR or XOR?

Comment: @Adam 2. says that one of f(a, b, c) and f(c, b, a) is false, 4. says that one is true. Maybe it would  be best to combine them into just 
2.  Exactly one of f(a, b, c) and f(c, b, a) is true

Comment: Neat challenge idea. For the scoring, maybe you can ask for the expected number of calls to f on a random n-element set. It should be easy to Monte Carlo simulate scores, as long as they're different enough. One issue is that people can pick an element *e* and then only do queries of the form f(e,x,y), to reduce this to a standard sorting problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Venn of \$n\$ number of sets

Given positive integer \$n\$, output \$n\$ 2D bool images with same width and height such that:

1. each image should be 4-connected, i.e. for each two pixels that are true, you can start from one and go up, down, left and right for some times to the other pixel, only passing through true pixels.
2. each image should have no hole, i.e. the component should be 4-connected
3. If we choose itself, its component or neither for each image, their intersection should be non-empty and 4-connected

### Examples (only a finite amount of solution shown, but there are infinitely many more)

Input: 1

Output:

```
.....
.***.
.**..
..*..
```

Input: 1

Output:

```
.....
...*.
.....
.....
```

Input: 2

Output:

```
..... .....
.***. ..**.
..... ..**.
..... .....
```

Input: 2

Output:

```
..... .....
.**.. ..**.
..**. ..**.
..... .....
```

Input: 3

Output:

```
..... ..... .....
.**.. ..**. .....
.**.. ..**. .***.
..... ..... .***.
```

Input: 4

Output:

```
...**.. .***... ....... .......
...**.. .***... ..***.. .......
...**.. .***... ..***.. ..****.
....... .***... ....... ..****.
....... ....... ....... ..****.
....... ....... ....... .......
```

Shortest code in each language win

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets)

Comment: im a little slow... what would be an example of an non-valid output?

Comment: So each image represents one Venn circle? This is a cool challenge. I would (1) say explicitly that each image represents one Venn circle, to make the question easier to understand, and (2) use a different term than "4-connected", which already has a different mathematical meaning.

Comment: @Lopsy I mean the `4-c` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity)

Comment: [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230065)

Answer (score 1):

## `Data.List.nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`

**Tags:** [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell), [list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list)

---

O(n^2). The [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) function removes duplicate elements from a list. In particular, it keeps only the first occurrence of each element. (The name [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) means `essence'.) It is a special case of [`nubBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy), which allows the programmer to supply their own equality test.

```
> nub [1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,4,3,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

### Goal

If you ever golfed in Haskell and you kind of needed to deduplicate a list, chances are that you chose a different route or were annoyed that there seems to be no solution shorter than importing `Data.List`.

In this challenge you will write a function `[a] -> [a]` (unnamed or named) which removes duplicates from a list, the order does not have to be preserved.

### Scoring

Since I don't think it's possible to get something shorter than 20 bytes and Haskell sometimes is really annoying to golf with if you want to use lengthy functions, the scoring mechanism will count tokens, please use [this program](https://tio.run/##fVPtattAEPzvp5heDJGwrdRp2h/GDoV80ICDCwn0h23KRT7ZIvKeuFsRpU2h79A37Iu4e4pc0hYqIel0Gu3M7s7eab/Z7bxLJ6obpZpj1cmsZeMmaqtzwgSly4mRgKo7uUfO6BVGI9yw7K8xOMX8ingZYzIeY234zBIbYq86OZUVT9R82D/uv@mfyHXcD@uwertUncoVE7VhLv3o6Ihzm7iKjg4OulHDmEFttL83RbGosyxcXVHZPJ8FNsuGQ@EJ6y95KQ/WeYFB2hsO5eVOe/PuBIOH1@GLw2CFw8khJEVJFKe4lgSTjcd4fDG77OTb0jrGuWadXFaUiiL6Y3Oae95vTDWtK702yYdnjclFzT6Zmtq4/0I6nbaqK9sBhHrwsmaylYpmbHV5jcLUt/bekBTa6C26KHIyXv6xmeCA7P1H7by5lIzN6uu30IksZB/5jX1AFjegBjK7Rx0@N5zhKAyDPUSGMCHgGyZprxTeuFQXmg3mN2abn9nC0lLYAzIKt4qmNo1Rt7HCUYolCCzx5jV6PThTFnkaYkSW5M9aGGnNmwY02L/UMQ7lfBJxUoY592m5fBGUyUtAaeunXMCB4jmzcVcsN0wSsVyoZ6ugYqnTlESoOsD4dnY@GyG15NlJvdmf9qGCsiZC1ApgH4c9BQ7ZeyxoQaoNGFrwGdHvuI3z91mdBOG9XhwLXUUP1q18I0vIyJdWOiji/1amFjS/dY/IGZZCL18to67MABaqdQh@fv@BALlizBrIQolZgzn3IxFmINhdRqWdjr2Ld7t/vCoT@ws) to count the tokens and use the generated template.

- If your solution is a named function or operator, it must not be defined in another file/module (ie. banning imports).
- Each solution may impose type constraints, each set of type constraints counts as its own language, compiler flags can be used without any restrictions.
- Your solution may not assume that the input is non-empty, however if you have an elegant solution which fails on empty input, feel free to include it in your post.

#### How are tokens counted?

Tokens are counted by using GHC's lexer which you can [`import Language.Haskell.Extes.Lexer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.20.0/candidate/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Lexer.html), except that newlines will count as a token too.

White space is ignored, every token of the language will count as one, no matter how long it is so `ma >>= f` will count as the three tokens `ma`, `>>=` and `f` the same holds true for string or number literals (eg. `"abc"` or `1.0` each count as 1).

### Test cases

```
[] -> []
[1] -> [1]
[1,1,1] -> [1]
[3,1,1,2] -> [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,3,2,1] -> [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something, but what stops the `import Data.List;nub` solution from winning with score 4?

Comment: @xnor: No you didn't, my bad. Fixed, I hope.

Comment: Hmm, this way it's still no good. Using `nubBy (==)` is still going to be hard to beat. Guess I need to ban imports completely :(

Comment: Yeah, I think banning imports is the way to go. I know past token-counting challenges have had "exploits" where the code payload is put into a huge string or number payload, the decompressed and executed by a general-purpose program. I don't see offhand a good way to do that in Haskell without imports though -- do you?

Comment: I tried writing a solution and the best general-type solution I got is the same as the one I'd use for golfing with imports banned, with 17 tokens. I'm unfortunately not seeing a way to take advantage of long built-ins like the scoring encourages. I see a shorter approach for a restricted type that feels both optimal and hard-to-improve to me. If you don't have some clever better method up your sleeve, I'd suggest a more complex task. Nice token-counting script by way, the number labelling makes it very clear.

Comment: @xnor: Without imports one could still embed an interpreter, I guess. [I was thinking earlier about this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49506077#49506077) and I think there's nothing wrong with counting literals as multiple tokens. However yeah, probably it's best to come up with a more complex task. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I don't really see how counting tokens is too much better, and it makes the challenge language specific.

Answer (score 1):

## Make a markdown Table of contents parser

A simple Code Golf challenge in the likes of the Markdown parser.

The parser should ignore normal text and other markup (without an `#` before it).

Some valid headers are: `### Header 3`, `# Header1`, `Text # Header`

Sample input:

```
# Hello
Lorem # Hello2
Hi this is normal text

## This is a subheader
Lorem ipsum

### Subsub
Solor di amet

# Hello again
This is more text!
```

sample output:

```
Hello
Hello2
- This is a subheader
--- Subsub
Hello again
```

Comment: What about `\`\`\``[linebreak]`# text in code`[linebreak]`\`\`\``? Or with indentation? What about where there is no space (still formats) : `#no space`? Or inside quote: `> # header`/spoiler: `>! #header`? Please specify these and any other edge cases.

Comment: I'd personally recommend trying to avoid so many edge cases. If you give a precise list of all of the cases that the parser has to care about and then just say something like "ignore any other markup" I think your challenge will be better.

Answer (score 1):

## Growth of the Jackpot (Tentative Name)

#### (Gauging interest)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

---

There is a money pot that gains $1 for every player currently in the game each turn. At any time, a player can decide to take the money and run or stay in the game hoping for a larger pot. If more than one player decides to leave at the same time, the money will be divided evenly among them, rounded down, with the remainder being put back in the pot. If after 100 rounds, there are still players left in the game, they will split whatever is in the pot at that time. Whoever has the most money at the end of the game wins.

Write a bot to play this game. You will always know the size of the pot, how many players are currently playing, how many were initially in the game, and the current first place amount of money.

---

On the surface, the optimal strategy is to bail out on turn \$\lceil{100n \over {2n - 1}}\rceil\$ (where \$n\$ is the number of players) because that turn guarantees that nobody can do better than you. But then if everyone does that, they'll split the pot and lose, so the best action to take is not immediately obvious.

---

One possible variant to round limits would be to have it cost each player $1 per turn they stay in the game, with each player starting with $100 and being forced to take the money and run when they have none left to contribute. Then the game could be run for several rounds.

Comment: [Kind of a one-shot form of Reaper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172102/lets-play-some-reaper-closed-for-submissions)

Comment: I like this. It allows for multiple simple strategies, but has a lot of depth and an interesting metagame aspect. To encourage complicated answers, I would recommend having bots play a few games in a row, to allow a bot to learn optimal timings vs given opponents.

Comment: If a bot may play several games, is the object to win as much money as possible, or to win as many games as possible?

Answer (score 1):

## Hungry Monster 9

> My first challenge. Feedback is appreciated.

A monster shaped like `2` is hungry and wants to become a `9`. To do so he will eat food, that is shaped like the number `1`, seven times.

```
0000000000
0000100000
0100000000
0000001000
0000020000
0100000000
0000000100
0010000000
0000001000
0000000000
```

## Challenge

It starts with a grid filled with `0`, containing the digit `2`, and seven times the digit `1`.
The `2` (aka the monster) needs to move to the closest `1`. Upon "eating" the number, `2` will change to `3`, and continue to move to the next closest number.

Write a program that outputs the next correct state.

## Input specifications

- The input grid is a rectangle and can be of any size. It doesn't need to be a square.
- The input can be at any state. For example a grid with a `6` and three times `1` left.
- The grid will contain exactly one digit higher than or equal to `2` (the "player").
- The grid will contain seven times or less the number `1`.

## Rules

- When the monster gets on the position of where a `1` is, its digit increases by 1.
- The monsters previous position becomes `0`.
- When the monster is `9`, it does not move.
- The monster can move in 8 directions (horizontally, vertically, diagonally).
- The monster moves to the closest `1`. If there are multiple closest, you may choose any of those. It is not required to be random.

## Example Input and Output

This is an example of the first 4 states (and example inputs/outputs):

```
0000000000
0000100000
0100000000
0000001000
0000020000
0100000000
0000000100
0010000000
0000001000
0000000000
```

```
0000000000
0000100000
0100000000
0000003000
0000000000
0100000000
0000000100
0010000000
0000001000
0000000000
```

```
0000000000
0000100000
0100030000
0000000000
0000000000
0100000000
0000000100
0010000000
0000001000
0000000000
```

```
0000000000
0000400000
0100000000
0000000000
0000000000
0100000000
0000000100
0010000000
0000001000
0000000000
```

The output is allowed to be an array of lines.
`["0000000000", "0100000000", "0000080000"]`

Comment: `If there are multiple closest, it can choose any of those.` Does it have to randomly choose, or can it (for example) always take the north-most?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork It does not have to be random. Your example is allowed. Thanks, I'll make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

## Low diversity quine.

A low diversity quine is a quine (program that outputs it's source code) that uses a low amount of distinct characters.

### Scoring:

As a code-golf challenge the program with the lowest score wins.

Score is calculated as: NumberOfDistinctCharacters x ByteCount

### Rules:

Standard quine rules apply. Most notably: **No source code reading**

Comment: Whitespace and brainfuck have a clear advantage :P. Also, the standard quine for a lot of languages is optimal here. Notably V.

Comment: *Pretty* sure we've had (something very close to) this before, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Shaggy I thought the same, but I'm not so sure anymore. I'm probably confusing it with [Eww, those bytes are gross](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/180356/52210), where answers use the least amount of distinct bytes as well, but when the input contains any of the bytes in your source code, they should remain in the output. So it's related to the source code and distinct bytes, but not a quine. Alternatively I could've confused it with [Write a Quine Suite](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163607/52210), where answers contain multiple quines that share none of the same characters

Comment: *that uses a low amount of distinct characters used* → *that uses a low amount of distinct characters* or *with a low amount of distinct characters used*

Answer (score 1):

## Dining philosopher problem

This question is motivated by the lack of concurrency related puzzles on PPCG. The goal of this question is to solve the Dining Philosophers Problem.

---

#### What is the dining philosophers problem (DPP) ?

The [DPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) is one of the most famous concurrency problem, used to illustrate what is a deadlock for instance.

*n* philosophers are dining together at a circular table. Between each philosopher, there is a fork. In order to eat, each philosopher should have two forks (one in each hand).

The problem is that, if all philosophers try to take the fork on their right, then wait until the one on their left (taken by the philosopher on their left) is available, they will wait forever.

Solving the problem is finding a strategy so that no philosopher waits forever.

---

#### Your program

Takes an input *n*, the number of philosophers (and the number of forks).
Run *n* philosophers in parallel, each philosopher output its dining events.

There are 4 different dining events possible:

1. Philosopher *i* takes the fork *j*;
2. Philosopher *i* tries to take the fork *j*, but fails (the fork is already taken);
3. Philosopher *i* release the fork *j*;
4. Philosopher *i* eats (and leave the table/release the forks and do not compete anymore).

A trace is correct if:

- A fork is taken by at most 1 philosopher at any time (between two events 1 for the same *j*, there must be an event 3 for that *j*).
- A philosopher only interacts with neighbourgs forks (in events 1, 2, 3, *j* is *i* or *(i+1)%n*).

The output format is a sequence of events. You can choose how to represent each event, but the following is suggested:

1. *i+j*
2. *i!j*
3. *i-j*
4. *i*

A (non-golfed) C version is available [here](https://gist.github.com/Bromind/3b611ac62676a0c4cf803555d40850c6), with output in plain english. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVTBbtswDD1bX0F0SCAn7tAeenK7LyiGXXZKg0CV5ViLYhmWXKwt8uv1JDrOZNfFgmG7KDL5SL5HkeGXW87blnySJVdNJm6NzZR8/Fx8GZikHlgqW9SCZd5GjvfNvrHi58bCItf1zqQnu7NAVUilja4KUQeePkI3tmrsRmm@S4ksLZSPmyAC7uAmJeiwbCeovwTuBLzBF43hlUTD5D4nnQcF4pREHl8L6/KOmNTPHR4VrPy5RnxOEX4HVzGJoqp2CXJ68S2gOJPIzSAP9/VQXiRDkkjQJRPKCPg4C2cllLpT@udkQ/5NOSm3Bz1LoTLqLU5NU5e@Byk5EPKkZeY@lGDmH3R3mtOopR@oP5Iw/0t5L1YwOxZ6trxp5i6jGbM9l2fPKghFdjJDUk4yTdPYzyHQbgOyBJ04kR7iR/TkcQcs4TqeDdcohEfYgMwTjKLTywexMBst4Xvo73A/TP56IFOIg9fn5eyZLFEXq7c8AV6weuHvT6s1snq39cxqSRFwjUODM@Tse6Zc5@gIvwAjX4TO6WipY3yG4A/o/AwYi3WhexAXepW6n9tRd5xtuexa28dyd1pB52HllVwn8PX7/X0C8@GOdY36u0o/tOvrZJlj@9u2vXnjuWJb016qY9gv)

#### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). You should, in addition, consider the following points:

- You must solve the problem concurrently, i.e. create one thread per philosopher and use usual atomic operations. Said otherwise, you should output a trace of an execution, not compute a possible scheduling.
- You can not rely on time to solve the problem (no such thing as: philosopher 1 waits 1 sec, philosopher 2 waits 2 sec, etc..). To generalise, you can not use the identifier of the philosopher to do something else than finding the neighbourg forks.
- If you add a TIO link in addition to your code, you can add any thread yield (or equivalent in your language) in the TIO version, in order to emphasize non-determinism.
- If you add a TIO link in addition to your code, you can add use an extra lock to avoid concurrency artifacts on standard output, on the TIO version. You can not use that lock to solve the problem (i.e. if we remove this lock, the solution must remain correct). In particular, you can use this lock to atomically do an event and output it.

Example: the TIO version of:

```
try = try_lock(fork_1)
if (try is success)
  output("1+1")
else
  output("1!1")
```

can be :

```
lock(output_mutex)
try = try_lock(fork_1)
if (try is success)
  output("1+1")
else
  output("1!1")
unlock(output_mutex)
yield()
```

#### Example run

for `n = 4`, the following are possible outcomes (notice that both are traces generated from the same program, it happened that the scheduling was not the same on both runs):

```
0+0
0+1
0
0-1
0-0
1+1
1+2
1
1-2
1-1
3+3
3+0
3
3-0
3-3
2+2
2+3
2
2-3
2-2
```

```
0+0
2+2
2+3
1+1
1!2
0!1
2
2-3
2-2
1-1
1+1
1+2
1
1-2
1-1
0-0
0+0
0+1
0
0-1
0-0
3+3
3+0
3
3-0
3-3
```

---

## Questions to be answered:

- The goal is to have a concurrent implementation of the problem (i.e. the scheduling of events should not be fixed, there should be a thread per philosopher, etc.). How to emphasize that in an understandable manner ?
- Concurrency leads to problems, such as interleaving in stdout. Here, what I have in mind is that when the philosopher thread takes a fork, it can atomically output it on stdout, in order to reflect what actually happens. Said otherwise, I'd like to propose a way to assume that the output reflects locks behavior. Another problem is that, for small `n`, the output is likely to be deterministic (thread `i` finishes before `i+1` is even started). Hence I'd like to allow the programmer to add any thread_yield() (or sleep, or anything that introduce non-determinism) to break that.
- This kind of puzzles, intended to be solve by distributed algorithms, is quite unusual on ppcg. Codegolf is a possible scoring system, but maybe there are better systems (like, the less synchronisation, etc.).

Comment: You have a typo in the introduction: *each philosopher should have **to** forks*

Comment: As a puzzle this isn't interesting: the solution is too well known. Concurrency is of dubious observability: certainly it can't be determined from the output or the timing, because that can equally be done by simulating green threads with a random number generator to select which state machine advances, and that's probably golfier than using semaphores or similar. IMO this isn't a good fit for the site.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't agree with your first argument : ppcg contains a lot of problem which solution is known. Concerning the second part, I agree: not using concurrency probably leads to a shorter code. However, the point of this question is to illustrate that concurrent programming is ignored on ppcg, while it is, in everyday programming, a real problem. That is why, I think, we should find a way to integrate problems based on concurrency. Surely code-golf is not the best rule, but not all problems on ppcg are code-golf (e.g. popularity). We should suitable rules for such programs.

Comment: (1) Emphasis on "*As a puzzle*". The presentation of this question seems to me to present it as a puzzle to be solved, and while there are questions like that on this site they tend not to be the best ones. If nothing else, once the first person solves it and posts an answer, everyone else can just copy that answer. (2) PPCG is almost the opposite of real world coding, where clarity is the most important criterion. If you can find a good winning criterion then that's great, but shoehorning a problem into a criterion which doesn't fit is to no-one's advantage.

Comment: I don't know much about concurrency, so I'll comment from the view of a general site member. It's weird to me that we're printing the trace which is easy to generate non-concurrently, with the hard-to-define requirement of it being generated concurrently buried underneath. I think it would make more sense for our code to implement each of the philosophers, under the requirement that simulating philosophers all running our code results them in all eating. This would mean explicitly specifying what input each philosopher gets at each step and what they can do, in a way that forces concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

## Sort a list using a stack and a queue

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Consider an unsorted list of length `n`, containing the integers `1` through `n`. Your job is to sort them using a stack (FIFO) and a queue (LIFO) and a single register. To do this, you have access to six commands

```
i    Input the next integer onto the register
o    Output the value of the register
Q    Place the value of the register at the tail of the queue (enqueue)
q    Place the value of the head of the queue in the register (dequeue)
S    Place the value of the register at the top of the stack (push)
s    Place the value of the top of the stack in the register (pop)
```

A few examples (sorting in ascending order):

```
Input:
 [1 2 3 4] 
Commands:
 ioioioio

Input:
 [3 2 4 1]
Commands:
 iQiSiQiosoqoqo
```

### Challenge

Write a  program or function that, given some (unsorted) list, returns a sequence of commands that outputs an ordered list. However, **the number of commands should grow as \$o(n^2)\$, i.e., strictly smaller than \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$**. That is, for sufficiently large \$n\$, you must always use less than \$cn^2\$ commands (with \$c\$ some positive constant) to sort the list.

- The input is flexible. The list of size \$n\$ may start from \$0\$ or from \$1\$ and will always contain all integers from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$ or from \$1\$ to \$n\$ respectively. You may take \$n\$ as a separate input if desired.
- The output is flexible. You may choose a different set of unambiguous command identifiers instead of `ioQqSs`. You may output as a string (which is allowed to contain superfluous characters such as delimiters, linebreaks, etc), or as an array or list of commands.
- Your entry must indicate the worst-case output size, e.g., \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, \$\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))\$, which must of course be strictly smaller than \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$.

---

A few notes:

- Things like `ii`, `qi`, `oo` should never happen. You only have one register, and overwriting it would mean you can no longer output the full sorted list.
- A naive approach would be to put the entire input in the queue `iQiQiQ...` and then cycling through the queue `qQqQqQ...` until the register contains the next integer in order. However, this approach would mean you have \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ cycling commands for \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ numbers, which would be \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ and thus does not meet the complexity requirement.

Comment: The [tag:restricted-complexity] tag means that your code must have a restricted complexity in at least one aspect, not that the output has a restricted growth rate. As it is, I can simply brute force and find the optimal output in all cases, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks for raising that point. I'm not sure if brute forcing will always be the shortest in byte count, so I would like to think that different approaches are still competitive. Perhaps I could change it such that the entire algorithm must run in o(n^2) (which would automatically disqualify O(n^2) output)? Or perhaps o(n^2) for the output, O(n^3) for the algorithm. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the time, brute-forcing ends up being the shortest approach. :( Also, yeah, requiring the algorithm to run in o(n^2) but still managing to get O(n^2) output means the answer is... weird. However, the other problem is that your code doesn't know which commands to execute from the beginning, and I'm half-confident that o(n^2) will be enough, but not really confident. I don't think the output can really be o(n). As for the specific complexity, well... no specific opinion yet. :P

Comment: Are you sure this is in \$O(n^2)\$? Something tells me the complexity might be bigger than that when all you have is a stack and a queue. You should also use LaTeX to format your big-O notation: `\$O(n)\$` `\$O(n \log n)\$` `\$O(n^2)\$`

Comment: @Beefster Like explained in the notes, you can do this in \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ by just using the queue, but I'll have to check if \$o(n^2)\$ is possible; I'll of course check before posting. Thanks re. MathJax, I forgot this was turned back on.

Comment: I think you need to work out \$c\$- i.e. you should probably put a hard cap on the number of commands. The worst-case naive approach comes out to \$n(n-1) \over 2\$ cycle commands for a total of \$n(n-1) + 2n\$ total commands. You can definitely always do better than that since the naive queue-only approach worst case is a reversed sequence, which is handled trivially by the stack.

Comment: BTW, I came up with the formula by noticing that it is a shrinking queue and you therefore need at most \$l-1\$ cycle commands to get to the correct element from any point in the queue. (where \$l\$ is the queue length)

Comment: Also I think I have the formula off by a bit: It should be \$n(n-1) + 4n\$ since you need \$2n\$ commands for both filling and emptying the queue.

Comment: In addition, skipping the queue for the first element cuts it down to \$(n-1)(n-2) + 4n - 2\$ total commands.

Comment: Following this mental thread, I suggest the following rule: "For any input sequence with length \$n \geq 3\$, you must output fewer than \$n^2 + n\$ commands."

Comment: Your queues work back to front compared to mine: I enqueue to the tail and dequeue from the head. Perhaps it would be cleanest to just talk about pushing to the queue, popping from the queue, pushing to the stack, and popping from the stack.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that the worst case is linear. For \$4 \le n \le 8\$ the worst case is \$4, 5, \ldots, n, 2, 3, 1\$ at cost \$6n - 10\$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking the same, but I didn't have time yet to verify this. And... have you never heard about left-hand-drive queues?

Answer (score 1):

### Performance-Based Resource Gathering/Trading

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

In this KoTH, the goal is to be the bot with the highest amount of money by the end of the game. Bots perform actions to earn money in turns. There are a set number of rounds in a game, and each round allows each bot to play. In a play, bots have set number of milliseconds to run as many turns as possible, growing their crops/trees/animals, mining for materials, or harvesting materials.

#### Earning Money

There are four basic "professions", though bots are not bound to a specific profession. These professions require land to collect resources, and land is zoned by its owner as one profession:

**Farming**

Farming uses turns to plant, grow, and harvest crops. There are three crops: wheat, carrot, and cotton. Each unit of land zoned for farming can hold up to 40 crops simultaneously. There is no randomness in farming. The crops are:

- Wheat: The most basic crop, wheat, takes 40 turns to grow. It is planted with 1 wheat seed, and grows into 2 wheat
- Carrot: Carrots are the fastest growing crop, taking only 16 turns to grow. Carrots are planted with one carrot, and grow into 4
- Cotton: Cotton grows very slowly, but is a valuable item in the economy. It is planted with 1 cotton seed, and produces 3 cotton in 96 turns.

**Ranching:**

Ranching uses land to raise animals, which can be used to produce meat and other goods. Ranching is only very mildly randomized. There are three animals: chickens, cows, and sheep.

- Chickens: A chicken takes up 2.5% of the land it occupies. Chickens lay eggs once every 8-10 turns, and an egg can be hatched into a chicken in 64 turns. Chickens last 192 turns before they stop producing eggs. Chickens can be harvested for 1 meat
- Cows: Cows do not produce items until they are harvested. A cow takes up 5% of the land it occupies, and are "mature" 144 turns after being bought. Mature cows can be harvested for 6-8 meat and 2 leather
- Sheep: A sheep takes up 6.25% of the land they occupy. Sheep last indefinitely, and produce wool every 112-132 turns. They can be sheared for 2 wool each time this happens. Sheep do not produce anything when harvested, and never stop producing wool

**Woodcutting:**

Land zoned for woodcutting contains 12 spaces for trees. Woodcutting is a moderately random-based profession. There are three types of trees available:

- Oak: Oak saplings take 120-132 turns to grow, and produce 8-16 wood
- Cedar: Cedar saplings take 84-96 turns to grow, and produce 5-9 wood
- Hemlock: Hemlock saplings take 240-280 turns to grow, and produce 14-22 wood

**Mining:**

Mining is a completely random-based profession. Each turn in which the bot mines produces one of three materials:

- Stone: Stone has a 65% chance
- Iron: Iron has a 30% chance
- Gold: Gold has a 5% chance

#### Economy/Raw Materials

You may be wondering: What do the bots do with all these materials? Well, factories can be built on land, and used to make new items. These items can be sold to NPC traders, or used by bots to improve their efficiency at a profession.

**Wood**: Wood is used for the creation of tools, construction of factories, and as a fuel source

**Stone:** Stone is used for construction and tools

**Iron:** Iron is used for the creation of tools and factories

**Gold:** Gold is highly sought after by traders

**Wheat:** Wheat is necessary to feed cows and sheep, as well as the creation of bread

**Carrot:** Carrots are necessary to feed chickens

**Cotton/Wool/Leather:** The Loom factory converts these materials into cloth, which is sold to traders or used to make clothes

**Eggs:** Eggs are necessary to make bread

#### Factories

There are three factories, each for a specific type of good:

**Loom:** The loom converts cotton, wool, and leather into cloth, and cloth into clothes. Clothes increase the amount of time to run turns by 20% per piece equipped, up to 3, for the next 5 rounds.

**Bakery:** The bakery converts wheat into flour. Flour and eggs are then converted into bread, which can be sold or equipped. When consumed, bread increases time to run turns by 25% for the next 2 rounds. Meat can also be consumed, but increases the time by 40% for 3 rounds.

**Smithy:** The smithy creates tools. These tools are: plow, trough, axe, and shovel. Each tool doubles the time for ticks in the round it is used.

#### Other

This is not complete, and many numbers still need to be added or changed to make things more equal between professions. Things like land still need to be figured out, but that's what the sandbox is for I suppose. This seems a little complicated, but each bot will probably stick with either a single profession or just be a factory owner.

Answer (score 1):

## Given a position of a chess piece and another square, determine if the chess piece attacks that square

### Input

Input would be in the form

> Qe4 c6

Where the first term denotes the piece and its position and the second term is the square we're interested in.

Labels for pieces are:
K - king
Q - queen
R - rook
B - bishop
N - knight
P or empty - pawn

In fact, the input could be left to be decided by the programmer, to make them creative in coming up with the most efficient input method, for example any of these could be valid, if the programmer decides so:

> Qe4, c6
>   [Qe4, c6]
>   Qe4c6
>   qe4-c6

Even the order could be reversed if that makes parsing easier. Basically the input could be left completely to the programmer's liberty.

## Output

So in the above case the input

> Qe4 c6

would give an output

> True

Because the queen on e4 indeed attacks c6. Outputs like 1 or any other boolean outputs would also be allowed.

An input like

> Nc3 a3

would produce

> False

because a knight on c3 doesn't attack a square on a3.

## Possible problems

There are some invalid inputs possible, like:
1. Wrong letter for a piece, like "Te2"
2. The coordinates which don't exist, like "k9"
3. The second square being the position of the piece itself, for example "Qa3 a3"

Should this be included in the rules or better not to not make it too complicated?

Comment: At least for code golf, all inputs are assumed valid because adding input validation tends to inflate scores significantly.

Answer (score 1):

## Randomly produce a (name of a language) source file that is possibly a quine

Write code in **any language** that randomly generate a **(name of a language)** (Java?) source file, meeting the two criteria:

- It must always (with probability 1) compile successfully in a (language) compiler and version of your choice.
- It must have non-zero probability to be a quine in (language).

You don't have to make it able to generate all possible programs, and the probability doesn't have to be uniform. The objective is to write a generator shorter than the shortest possible quine in (language) compressed. Technically your code could be deterministic and generate only one program, that is a quine. But it isn't supposed to be competitive.

Your code must not have the potential to damage the computer. But it doesn't matter what the generated (language) program does when it is not the quine that qualifies your answer.

(Restrictions about compiler flags to be added.)

You could either use the built-in random functions and assume they generate true random numbers, or request random information from the input (details to be added). Your code only need to have probability 1 to terminate.

Shortest code wins.

---

#### Possible rule

You may not call any (language) compiler or anything else that could check (language) syntax.

---

I was thinking about C++, but there are short patterns to execute any binary machine code. The language should also have a verbose structure, and not a too short quine.

Candidates: Java, Haskell, Shakespeare Programming Language, Mornington Crescent, SQL, ferNANDo.

Or: Generate a PNG file that is possibly this image. But that may depend to much on a PNG library, and the other part is trivial.

Comment: @trichoplax The objective is to write a generator (in any language) shorter than the shortest possible quine (in a specific target language) compressed.

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, unless we argue about the case that is possible but has probability 0 to not terminate.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that we can print a normal-ish quine, but with all its strings replaced with random strings without quotes, newlines and other offending characters?

Comment: As of currently, yes. I hope there are better solutions, but I'm worrying about that this is actually the best solution, and makes it trivial.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow restrict a Java program from destroying the computer with a finite amount of code? If so, generating all strings, trying to compile them and running them parallelly until any happens to be a quine might or might not be even shorter.

Comment: @someone The generator should not destroy the computer. But as of currently it doesn't disallow trying all strings. Maybe I'll forbid calling the Java compiler or syntax checker.

Comment: Curiously, this seems similar in concept to [Solve Subset-Sum in polynomial time (…if P = NP)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182733/solve-subset-sum-in-polynomial-time-if-p-np).

Comment: I'm actually having trouble imagining how to beat a hardcoded quine. Generating nontrivial valid code seems hard. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @xnor I think hardcoding a quine except for a string is most likely going to win. So I'm looking for a language that potentially allows more approaches. I may also change it to generate a program for a task other than quine.

Answer (score 1):

## Draw a regular prism

**Input**

The input is a single integer `i` between 3 and 8.

**Output**

The image of a regular prism with the two regular polygonal faces having `i` edges each.  For example, if `i=3` your code should draw a triangular prism using two equilateral triangles.

**Rules**

The diameter of the polygonal (i.e. triangular if `i=3`) faces must be at least  200 pixels as should the distance between the regular faces.  You can show the image at any angle you like as long as at least two faces of the prism are visible, including one of the two regular polygonal faces.

The edges of the prism that are visible should be in black and the edges that are not visible should be drawn with dotted black lines, a dotted line being a line where in at least 3 distinct, non-connected places (meaning separated by black) there's an absence of black color.

**Examples**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: You have your examples with the bases aligned. Is that required for output?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork No. Unless you think it should be?

Answer (score 1):

## Finding distinct road sections

I was recently working on a grid-based road procedural generator, and thought of a neat idea for a new challenge:

### The Task

Given a square (equal width and height) 2d array in which each item is one of 2 distinct values (of your choice): grass and road (I will use `_` and `#` in examples), output the grid modified such that each distinct segment of road tiles has had its values changed to a unique value.

Two road tiles are considered to be part of the same segment if they neighbor each other in at least 1 cardinal directions.
Diagonal neighbors are not considered to be part of the same segment (unless they are connected cardinally elsewhere)
A single road tile with no connections is considered to be its own distinct segment.

You may choose the 2 input values used, and all output values used.
"Grass" tiles must remain unchanged.

You may assume there will always be at least 1 road segment, and that the array dimensions will be no larger than 64 by 64

### Example:

Input:

```
___#__######____
_###__#_#_______
___#_##_########
___#____________
####_#######__##
_#_#_#__________
_#_#_#______####
___#_#__________
##_#_##_________
______#_________
_______#_#######
______##________
__###_#_______##
_##_____________
__#######_______
__#_____________
```

`_` is "grass" and `#` is "road"

Output:

```
___3__111111____
_333__1_1_______
___3_11_11111111
___3____________
3333_4444444__22
_3_3_4__________
_3_3_4______5555
___3_4__________
66_3_44_________
______4_________
_______7_8888888
______77________
__000_7_______99
_00_____________
__0000000_______
__0_____________
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes *in each language* wins

### Test cases

**TBA**

## Sandbox

- I feel like the task is poorly worded, but can't think of a better way to word it.

Comment: This seems really familiar, but I can't seem to find a dupe...

Comment: I'm worried about the numbering - is there a defined numbering scheme? The way you have it, it starts from the bottom left and reads to top right.  But most (read: ALL) programming languages read from top left to bottom right.

Comment: I would specify either the numbering relation, or that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @mackycheese21 `You may choose the 2 input values used, and all output values used.`

Answer (score 1):

## Draw an Image on the screen efficiently

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Imagine you have a special rectangular screen made of square pixels. It consists of \$n\$ rows and \$m\$ columns. For every row and every column there is one swich (so \$n + m\$ switches in total). To turn a certain pixel on - let's say  at position \$(i,j)\$ - we can press switch \$i\$ (of the row switches) and switch \$j\$ (of the column switches) at the same time.

As soon as some pixel has been turned on, it stays on, even if we press the same combination of switches again. **META: Is this a good idea? Or should we say that each pixel should be turned on exactly once and may not be activated again?**

But we can also press an arbitrary number of switches at the same time: Lets say we press switches \$0,2,3\$ of the row switches and \$1,5\$ of the column switches, then all the pixels \$(i,j)\$ with \$i \in \{0,2,3\}\$ and \$j \in \{1,5\}\$ will get turned on, so all the pixels \$(0,1),(0,5),(2,1),(2,5),(3,1),(3,5)\$.

If we now want to draw a picture on the screen you could do that pixel for pixel, and we'd need \$n \cdot m\$ actions in the worst case - that is, when we have to turn on every pixel. But as we can press an arbitrary number of switches at the same time, we can do better than that. We can for example do row by row: This means we select one switch for the current row, and all necessary column switches to activate all the pixels we need for this row, so in total we would need \$\min\{n,m\}\$ actions. But can we do better than that?

The task is now to write a program that given some black and white image computes a *shortest* sequence of actions (=simultaneous switch activations) that turns on exactly all the white pixels of the given image.

#### Details

- You can also take a matrix/list of lists as input, or a list of the coordinates of the active pixels.
- You can additionally take the size \$(n,m)\$ as an input (or \$(n-1,m-1)\$ if you prefer.
- The output is also flexible: You can represent every action as a list of two lists with the corresponding indices of the switches where each of the indices are in \$\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\$ or \$\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}\$ respectively (or also 1-based indexing is fine), or alternatively you enumreate all switches as \$\{0,1,2,\ldots,n+m-1\}\$ and use just one list to represent this action.

  Alternatively you can also just use lists of size \$n\$ and \$m\$ (or one of size \$m+n\$) with truthy and falsey values representing the switches that get activated.

**Related:** [Matrices Generated Using Rectangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154193/matrices-generated-using-rectangles)

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that the switches don't stay on after an action (i.e. we don't spend actions deactivating them). I'm not sure if it was the use of the word "switch" over "button" that made me think this would be the case but it may be worth running it past some other people.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks a lot for the effort of going through this draft! Is "button" used more for switched that just make a momentary contact? To be honest the alternative challenge that include also switching off the switches would maybe be even more interesting!

Comment: There are probably quite a few variations of this that would be fun (I'm still thinking about your meta question)! In any case, where I live I think that is the case in that most people would say my laptop has a power button, but the room I'm in has lights controlled by a switch.

Comment: Maybe add restricted-complexity, if this is even possible in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

Moved to [Make Gimbap cutter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186550/make-gimbap-cutter)

Comment: I don't understand how your last test case follows your rules (and other test cases), since I only see two valid Gimbap, `@)` and `@)))` in the input.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork There is two valid Gimbap, `@)` and `@)))`, than split them to `@)` and `@) @) @)`. So output is `@) @) @) @)`. I'm not that good at English, though. Can you suggest me the way to make question clearer?

Comment: Oh, so the output is *only* the valid Gimbap? That makes more sense. Will the input ever contain anything other than `@` or `)`? I would recommend it doesn't.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Input is made with only `@` and `)`.

Comment: Would `)))@)` be a valid input?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz It would. Then output will be `@)`. I'll add that to example.

Comment: So in other words: count all `)`s which occur after the first `@` and output that many `@)` separated by spaces?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yup. But I moved it into main site.

Comment: When you do that you should edit the sandbox post to just be a link to the question on the main site, and then delete it, as described in the second paragraph at the top of this page.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks you. I'll edit my posts.

Answer (score 1):

## Cumbersome IO format [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

The cops' task is to write a program in language A to solve (task about integer lists 1) and a program in language B to solve (task about integer lists 2). The second program must be able to use the output of the first program.

Others could golf your programs. Highest (C + total length of your programs) / (C + minimum total length of the programs without the restriction) wins. (C is a fixed constant to be chosen.)

(Details to be written. The format would be similar to [The Bowlers-Golfers Fraction War](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37797/25180). Minimum lengths of the two parts would be taken from other challenges.)

Comment: Would a pair of languages that both implicitly eval input and uneval output (and since it's a integer list, pretty much all golfing languages I know of work like that for lists) work as a optimal (besides the program itself) solution? What does "program length" in the score formula stand for? The score seems to always be 1 to me.

Comment: @someone Highest score wins. This is a bowling challenge to find two languages which work the worst with the other one's IO format. But I think this may not work well, as there isn't much to do after you finds the languages.

Answer (score 1):

## Gitify a complete graph

Give a natural number `n = 1, 2, ...`, create a [git](https://git-scm.com/) repository that represents a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of size `n`.

#### Details

- A complete graph is a graph, where every node is connected to every other node (except for itself).
- The graph is represented as follows: Each commit is the equivalent of one node. And edge is represented by a parent/child relationship of two commits, that is, one commit must have the other as a parent.
- You must create a local repository. You can use `git` itself or other libraries, but you can also create it by writing the raw files. You must include all languages, tools or non-standard libraries of your language/s of choice you use in the title.
- The repo created must be readable with the current git version `2.37.x`, that is when you execute `git log --graph --oneline` after you created the repo the graph should be visible (usually probably not in a very nice layout if it is a complete graph).

#### Example Outputs

If we use `bash` with `git` installed, can execute following commands to get the outputs for `n = 1, 2, 3`. Note that these programs are not solutions to the challenge themselves (they don't take `n` as an input) but merely generate a valid output repository.

| Graph Size | Bash |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `git init;git commit --allow-empty -m x` |
| 2 | `git init;git commit --allow-empty -m x;git commit --allow-empty -m x` |
| 3 | `git init;git commit --allow-empty -m x;git commit --allow-empty -m x;git checkout -b first HEAD^;git merge master --no-ff -m x` |

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph)[git](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git)

#### META:

I've decided to simplify the challenge to just create a complete graph instead of arbitrary graphs.

<s>Given a undirected connected graph, create a git repository with a commit graph that is isomorphic to the input graph.</s>

- This is just a rough idea: I first should think about what kind of graphs can actually be represented in a git repository. (the input format could be flexible: take an adjacency matrix or e.g. a list of edges or maybe some native graph structure)
- another idea would be following: given some \$n =1,2,3,\ldots\$ create *complete graph* of \$n\$ nodes

Comment: Should _adjecency_ read _adj**a**cency_?

Comment: @JonathanFrech yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Moved here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187132/find-the-diameter-of-a-word-graph)

Comment: It would be good to include the words "*diameter*" and "*graph*". I don't think this particular graph statistic has been the subject of a question before, but it could well come up again in the future and then those search terms would make it easier to use this as a dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

## Digit Sum of Sum of Digit Sums

Input: An integer from 1 to 1000 (known as N)
Expected behavior: The code will go through the first N integers, and work out the digit sum for each integer, the code will then take these digit sums and add these together. The code will then take this total and work out the digit sum for that number. The final number is the expected output.

**Example 1:**

Input: 12

Output: 6

Behavior:

```
1) Numbers
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
2) Digit Sums
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3
3) Sum of Digit Sums
51
4) Digit Sum of Sum of Digit Sums
6
```

**Example 2:**

Input: 20

Output: 3

Behavior:

```
1) Numbers
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
2) Digit Sums
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2
3) Sum of Digit Sums
102
4) Digit Sum of Sum of Digit Sums
3
```

There are no restrictions on language type as long as the standard loopholes are avoided.
Please demonstrate your code using the last three digits of your current reputation score.

This is code-golf, the shortest number of characters in code will be deemed the winner. In the event of a tie, the one with highest popular answer will be crowned the winner. If both answers are tied in terms of popularity and size, a fight to the death will be used to declare the winner (just kidding...)

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this? Motivation is part of a good question.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

When dealing with data in two dimensions, data scientists looove to see straight lines emerge, as they can use a simple linear regression to model it - meaning we assume it is in the form of y=mx+b, and all that's left is to find the best m and b to describe the data.

There are several ways to fit a line to any data (I saw there was a challenge with Ordinary Least Squares once), however one of the most flexible one is gradient descent.

When given vectors X and Y, we start with an initial guess of m and b, then iteratively update them, and hopefully we get a better fit when we're done.

We give a "grade" to our current fitted line with mse (the lower the grade - the better the fit):

```
loss = mean((y - (m * x + b)) ** 2 for x, y in zip(X, Y))
```

And in each iteration we change m and b using the gradient of that same grade:

```
b -= 2 * alpha * mean((m * x + b) - y for x, y in zip(X, Y))
m -= 2 * alpha * mean(((m * x + b) - y) * x for x, y in zip(X, Y))
```

Here alpha is the learning rate (usually smaller than 1), used to keep the steps small enough to advance towards the minimum grade, rather than overstepping it.

The last question asked is when should we stop these iterations. We (a bit arbitrarily) impose two conditions:

1. The absolute relative change in the grade between two iterations `abs(grade1 - grade2)/grade1` is changed by less than some given epsilon, and/or
2. A given number of iterations N has been performed already.

p.s. I started by assuming the data is just y(x), however this method may be easily extended to an arbitrary number of free variables and one dependent variable.

## Challenge

Write a program that accepts inputs: X, Y, m, b, epsilon, N and returns the updated m and updated b after performing gradient descent as described.

### corner cases:

- X and Y may be empty, in which case m and b are returned unchanged.

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: This is in need of a woked example and a fee test cases.

Comment: What does `mean` mean? What does `zip` mean? Those should be made clear, just like you made `alpha` clear.

Answer (score 1):

## Some enchanted `ave`ning

(you may see a stranger across a crowded room).

This is one part of a multi-part series inspired by various built-ins in R. Credit goes to [digEmAll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41725/digemall) for suggesting this one.

`ave` calculates particular grouped values of a list.

For example, we would group `x` in the following way based on the criteria given in `f`:

```r
x = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5]
f = [[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]]

     x f1 f2
[1,] 2  1  1    -> group [1,1]
[2,] 1  2  1    -> group [2,1]
[3,] 3  2  2    -> group [2,2]
[4,] 5  2  2    -> group [2,2]
[5,] 4  1  2    -> group [1,2]
[6,] 1  2  1    -> group [2,1]
[7,] 5  1  1    -> group [1,1]
[8,] 5  1  2    -> group [1,2]
```

Then for each group, we apply a given function (in R, the default is `mean`), let's say `sum`:

```r
group [1,1]: 2, 5 -> sum = 7
group [2,1]: 1, 1 -> sum = 2
group [2,2]: 3, 5 -> sum = 8
group [1,2]: 4, 5 -> sum = 9
```

Then we replace each value in the group by the group sum, resulting in an output of:

`[7, 2, 8, 8, 9, 2, 7, 9]`

### Inputs:

- a list `x` of integers
- a list of lists `f` or an arbitrary number of lists, each of length equal to `x`; these are the *factors* to group on
- a black-box function `FUN` that takes a list of integers and returns a single integer value

### Output

- a list `o` of length equal to `x` where each element `o[i]` is equal to `FUN(group(x[i]))`, or as the documentation says:

  > A numeric vector, say `y` of length `length(x)`. If `f` is `g1`, `g2`, e.g., `y[i]` is equal to `FUN(x[j], for all j with g1[j] == g1[i] and g2[j] == g2[i])`.

### Rules

- Input can be in any order and in many flexible output formats.
- You may assume that the outputs will always result in integers.
- If your language has a builtin for this for some reason, please also implement your own solution.

---

## Sandbox questions/notes:

- I've done two of these so far and found a reference to a musical that is somewhat appropriate, any suggestion is appreciated there.
- Need to add test cases
- Need to work a bit harder on the explanation of how `ave` works.

Comment: You could call this something along the lines of "`Ave` Maria von Trapp"? Aside from that I understood your description well enough to write a (poor) answer.

Answer (score 1):

[*Proposed alternative to this*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17818#17818)

## Golf an H interpreter

H is a text-based, weakly-typed string concatenation language. You task is to run an H script. You may do so by creating an interpreter, a compiler, a transpiler, or by any other reasonable means.

### Definitions

Anything not defined herein is undefined behaviour and your implementation does neither have to support it nor does it need to throw an error. This includes unmatched quotes, invalid escapes, usage of variables before definition, etc. All given H scripts will abide by all the rules as stated.

#### General H syntax

**Scripts**: One or more lines, each containing zero or more statements, optionally followed by a comment.

**White-space**: you only have to support spaces in strings (tabs are escaped), plus tabs and/or spaces leading up to a comment.

**Operators**: There's only one, `+`, which is string concatenation.

**Comments** begin with `#` and continue until the end of the line. `#` may be prefixed by one or more spaces and/or tabs.

***name***: a sequence of *exactly* 4 single-case ASCII letters `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]` (you decide the scheme)

***value***: a `+`-delimited sequence of one or more strings (see below) and/or previously defined names. The combined value will never exceed 1000 characters.

#### Strings

Opened and closed by `"` and support ASCII 32–126 but with the following escape sequences:

`\\`: the literal backslash character; `\`

`\n`: a line break; CR, LF, CRLF, or LFCR (you decide)

`\"`: a quotes symbol; `"`

`\t`: a tab character; 	 (HT) or 2, 4, or 8 spaces (you decide)

A string matching the regex `0|-?[1-9]\d?\d?` (i.e. look like an integer) may be left unquoted.

#### Statements

Terminated by `;` but may not span multiple lines. There are only three types of H statements:

**`def name=value;`** sets the variable **`name`** to the given **`value`**.

**`print(value);`** prints **`value`** without trailing line break.

**`input(value;name);`** prints **`value`** without trailing line break,  allows the user to enter a sequence of characters that extend that line, and assigns the characters to *`name`*. Any subsequent output begins on the next line.

### Test script

The following assumes you have decided on the uppercase variable name scheme:

```
def HELO="Hello, ";
def HSMO=HELO+"strange"+-1;print("");
input(HSMO+"what is your name?";NAME);         #enter "User A" via stdin
#print(-123)   # nope
print(HELO+"\""+NAME+"\"\n\tthis isn't APL\\"+360+"!");

#done
print(-12+34)	# note the tab before #
```

Here is the equivalent using a lowercase variable name scheme:

```
def helo="Hello, ";
def hsmo=helo+"strange"+-1;print("");
input(hsmo+"what is your name?";name);         #enter "User A" via stdin
#print(-123)   # nope
print(helo+"\""+name+"\"\n\tthis isn't APL\\"+360+"!");

#done
print(-12+34)	# note the tab before #
```

Running the appropriate script, and entering `User A` should, according to the scheme where `\t` means ASCII 9 (HT), leave the console/screen/window showing:

```
Hello, strange-1what is your name?User A
Hello, "User A"
	this isn't APL\360!-1234
```

If instead you decided that `\t` means four spaces, it should show:

```
Hello, strange-1what is your name?User A
Hello, "User A"
    this isn't APL\360!-1234
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [interactive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive)

Comment: You may want to explicitly state that `User A` is the STDIN-input in the Test script. I must admit I just can't read and read past the explanation of `input(value;name);` when going through the test script and was thinking: where is `def name="User A";`. And based on "_Anything not defined herein is undefined behaviour and your implementation does neither have to support it nor does it need to throw an error._" we can assume all scripts are valid, so no `"` that are unmatched, and no variable used before it is defined, and stuff like that?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen How is it now?

Comment: Perfect. :) I had already upvoted I see. Everything is clear to me now.

Comment: @UserA No. There is an overwhelming consensus that [one should avoid bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/43319).

Comment: @UserA It is very probably that many of the solutions will allow all of those any way.

Answer (score 1):

## Switch the colour of the largest non-unique connected shape

Given a rectangular grid of square cells, find the non-unique connected shapes with the largest area, and switch their colour

## Input

- A rectangular grid of cells, each of which has 1 of 2 distinct values ("colours")
- You can choose to accept any of

  - an image with only 2 distinct pixel colours
  - text with only 2 distinct characters (also allowing newlines for forming a rectangle)
  - a 2d array, with each element having 1 of 2 distinct values
  - a 1d array, plus a width and/or height

The 2 distinct values will be referred to as "colours", but the rules apply similarly for all of the permitted formats

## Output

- A rectangular grid of cells in the same format as the input, using the same 2 colours
- For each shape required to be changed, all of its cells have been switched to the other colour

## Rules

- Each cell is part of a connected shape, which contains all cells of the same colour that can be reached by a path made up only of vertical or horizontal steps to adjacent cells of the same colour (no diagonal steps)
- The grid does not wrap: a shape cannot be connected across the outer boundary
- A shape is ***identical*** to another if it can be made to coincide exactly with it by any combination of

  - translation
  - rotation by an integer multiple of 90 degrees
  - reflection in any vertical or horizontal line
  - switching its colour
- A shape is ***unique*** if no other shape is identical to it
- The ***area*** of a shape is the number of cells it contains
- The shapes to be changed are those with the largest area, of those that are non-unique
- If 2 or more distinct shapes are non-unique and have the largest area, all instances of each distinct shape must be changed
- If there are no non-unique shapes, the output is the same as the input
- A grid (input or output) may sometimes contain only 1 of the 2 colours

## Test cases

Each test case is an input followed by its unique correct output

```
.  .

..  ..

.#  #.

.#  .#
..  ..

.#  #.
#.  .#

..#  ...
...  ...
.#.  ...

.......  .......
##.....  .......
#.....#  .......
.....##  .......

....##.  ....##.
##..##.  ....##.
#.....#  .......
.....##  .......

#.....###.  ..........
#.......#.  ..........
##...##...  ..........
.....##...  ..........
##........  ..........
##..####..  ....####..

.......###  .......###
..##..####  ......####
..#..###.#  .....#####
....###..#  ....######
...#######  ...#######

.......###  #######...
.##...####  ######....
.#...###.#  #####.....
....###..#  ####......
...#######  ###.......

........####  ########....
.###...#...#  ########....
.#..#.#.##.#  ##..##..##..
.###.###...#  ####........
....########  ####........

........####  ########....
.###...#...#  ########....
.#..#.#....#  ##..##......
.###.###...#  ####........
....########  ####........
```

The same test cases with colour coding for human reading (click image for larger version):

[image: test cases with colour coding]

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score is the number of bytes in your source code. For each language, the code with the lowest score wins

---

## Sandbox thoughts

- Any important/useful test cases welcome
- Is there a more useful format for 2d test cases?
- Are there 2 distinct characters that would make human reading easier?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Can anything be made clearer or more succinct?
- I'm also trying to think of a better name

Comment: I think using "remove" and "change" to mean the same thing is confusing. If I understand correctly, "removing" means to change the colour of, right? That wasn't very intuitive to me on my first reading.

Comment: Ah good point. Thank you. I will try and make that consistent throughout

Answer (score 1):

## Manage a todo list using Cypher (WIP)

## Introduction

A list is a common, well-understood data structure. Neo4j's property graph model can represent any data structure. Using the Cypher query language, write a collection of statements for managing a todolist

- inspired by [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com) and [Todo-Backend](https://www.todobackend.com)

## Challenge

Manage a todo list using parameterized Cypher.

Todo list items are composed of two pieces of information:

- `todo:string` - the textual content describing the thing to do
- `completed:boolean` - whether this todo has been done

Todo list operations:

- add new, view, edit, remove, complete, un-complete individual todo list item
- re-order todo list item
- view all items
- view all completed items
- view all "active" items (items not yet completed)
- complete all todo list items

Considerations:

- empty todo list

Out of scope:

- multiple lists

## Answer Format

For each operation, provide a code block of Cypher. Identify the operation with its description. Separate each operation with a `---` line. Like this...

1. Create an empty node:

```
CREATE ()
```

---

2. Create a generic relationship:

```
CREATE ()-[:RELATES_TO]->()
```

### Proposed tags

[cypher] [graph-theory]

Comment: (1) This is a long way from being self-contained. What's Neo4j? (Sounds like a Java library). What's Cypher? (2) The operations need more explanation, particularly those which rely on properties which haven't been mentioned. (Reorder? But there's no position-in-order property. Operations on individual item: what's its identity?). (3) This site discourages questions which restrict answers to a single language unless there's a good reason for the restriction. I don't see a good reason here.

Answer (score 1):

### Can the cursor reach the bottom?

A cursor position is valid if either of its two sides touches whitespace (i.e. a space or a newline(CR+LF or LF, depending on your OS)). The input will always consist of valid cursor positions.

This takes one input(a character matrix), and for a cursor on the up right corner of the input, can the cursor reach the bottom of the input?

Example input:

```
 ..... Same, delete text like this in order
 ......
. . . .
.      Same to get normal input
...... Same
```

The cursor can reach the bottom in this case. This process of moving the cursor will work: down, right(touches spaces on the left), down(touches spaces on the right), down, right(touches spaces on both sides) 6 times, and down(touching spaces and a linefeed).

Notably, this will also work:

```
  Code Golf deletes trailing whitespace by default
..
. trailing
```

The cursor starts at the up-right corner. After moving right two times, it can move down (due to touching a newline character). Then, it can move down, which touches the bottom of the line.

This example will not work:

```
 ...
... Same reason as above
```

The cursor cannot move down, as there is no sufficient whitespace to be touched.

Answer (score 1):

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188005/print-the-last-middle-and-first-character-of-your-code)

Comment: Interesting challenge, but I'm afraid a lot of trivial solutions exist. E.g. `123` which prints `123` in many languages. More interesting would be to require all three/four characters to be unique, and that they be printed in reverse.

Comment: now that this has been posted, you can edit it to only include a link to your post and delete it :-)

Answer (score 1):

## There's an echo in my array... echo in my array... my array...

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188177/theres-an-echo-in-my-array-echo-in-my-array-my-array).  Thanks for all of the suggestions and happy golfing!

Comment: "0≤n<1000" The input has 0–1000 elements or the elements are in the range 0–1000, or both?

Comment: Can there not be multiple correct solutions?

Comment: Will the echo ever begin at the first element?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how the echo works. Why can `[2,4,6]` not be `[1,2,3]` with an echo overlapping at the first element?

Comment: In fact, would there be one solution for each step, so dividing the input by 2 is always a valid solution?

Comment: @Adám ah yes, that's why echo cannot begin at the first element.  The echo'd version will always be longer than the original un-echoed version.  I'll clarify that.

Comment: @Adám have updated rules and test cases from your comments. Thanks!

Comment: As suggestion: if there is no echo, don't output nothing or `false` - the challenge is to correct the echo. If there is none, the echo is corrected to be... no different from the input. In a bid for consistency, I would therefore suggest that if there is no echo, they should output the original input, since that is the 'normal' version of the array.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest to make the program return the *shortest* possible array in the case of multiple solutions, to remove the most possible reverb - i.e choose the one that removes the *most* values from the input.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi I've been trying to come up with a case where there are multiple solutions, and cannot. You can easily have many echo'd versions for a given un-echo'd version, but there seems to only be one or zero un-echo'd versions for an echo'd version. I'm not a mathematician, so I cannot conclusively prove this, and I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I don't see a way that a correctly-constructed echo'd version could produce more than one answer.

Comment: @gwaugh after further consideration, I have come to the conclusion that you're correct. It's like a Fourier transform: every wave function always have a unique value, either in terms of phase or magnitude. Here, the phase is always different, and since the phase is shifted, the 'transform' of these numbers (imagining they are Y values at the X point of their index) must also be unique. So feel free to remove that rule - there can never be two answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Story

I began studying the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

And noticed this pattern in the numbers that go to 1 in one odd step, like 5,10,20,21,40,42... and looke in up on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A055086) and found this formula.

\$floor(sqrt(4*n + 1)) - 1\$

Which can plot these numbers in their natural order like so;

\$\frac{\left(8\cdot2^{\operatorname{floor}\left(\sqrt{4\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)+1}\right)}-2^{\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\sqrt{4\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)+1}\right)-1-\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{\left(4\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)+1-\operatorname{floor}\left(\sqrt{4\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)+1}\right)^2\right)}{2}\right)\right)}\right)}{3}\$

Then I looked at numbers going to 1 in two steps, like 3,6,12,13,24,26...
Where I found another pattern that I could not find a formula for on OEIS

```
long nth(int n){if(n>241)return -1;return (((1<<Y[n]+5)-(1<<1+Y[n]-((Z[n]&1)+Z[n]*3)))/3-(1<<Y[n]-2*X[n]-(2*(Z[n]&1)+Z[n]*3)))/3;}
```

With `X[],Y[] and Z[]` being these lookup-tables

```
 int[]X=new int[]{
 0, 
 0, 
 0,  1, 
 0,  1, 
 0,  1,  2, 
 0,  1,  2,                              0,
 0,  1,  2,  3,                          0,                          0, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,                          0,  1,                      0, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,                      0,  1,                      0,  1, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,                      0,  1,  2,                  0,  1, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,                  0,  1,  2,                  0,  1,  2,
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,                  0,  1,  2,  3,              0,  1,  2,                  0,
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,              0,  1,  2,  3,              0,  1,  2,  3,              0,              0, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,              0,  1,  2,  3,  4,          0,  1,  2,  3,              0,  1,          0, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,          0,  1,  2,  3,  4,          0,  1,  2,  3,  4,          0,  1,          0,  1, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,          0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,      0,  1,  2,  3,  4,          0,  1,  2,      0,  1, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,      0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,      0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,      0,  1,  2,      0,  1,  2, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,      0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,      0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,      0, 
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,  3,  1, 2
 };
 int[]Y=new int[]{
 0, 
 1, 
 2,  2, 
 3,  3, 
 4,  4,  4, 
 5,  5,  5,                              5,
 6,  6,  6,  6,                          6,                          6, 
 7,  7,  7,  7,                          7,  7,                      7, 
 8,  8,  8,  8,  8,                      8,  8,                      8,  8, 
 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,                      9,  9,  9,                  9,  9, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,                 10, 10, 10,                 10, 10, 10,
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,                 11, 11, 11, 11,             11, 11, 11,                 11,
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,             12, 12, 12, 12,             12, 12, 12, 12,             12,             12, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,             13, 13, 13, 13, 13,         13, 13, 13, 13,             13, 13,         13, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14,         14, 14, 14, 14, 14,         14, 14, 14, 14, 14,         14, 14,         14, 14, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,         15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,     15, 15, 15, 15, 15,         15, 15, 15,     15, 15, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,     16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,     16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,     16, 16, 16,     16, 16, 16, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17,     17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17,     17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17,     17, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18
};
int[]Z=new int[]{
0, 
0, 
0,  0, 
0,  0, 
0,  0,  0, 
0,  0,  0,                              1,
0,  0,  0,  0,                          1,                          2, 
0,  0,  0,  0,                          1,  1,                      2, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,                      1,  1,                      2,  2, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,                      1,  1,  1,                  2,  2, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,                  1,  1,  1,                  2,  2,  2,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,                  1,  1,  1,  1,              2,  2,  2,                  3,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,              1,  1,  1,  1,              2,  2,  2,  2,              3,              4, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,              1,  1,  1,  1,  1,          2,  2,  2,  2,              3,  3,          4, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,          1,  1,  1,  1,  1,          2,  2,  2,  2,  2,          3,  3,          4,  4, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,          1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,      2,  2,  2,  2,  2,          3,  3,  3,      4,  4, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,      1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,      2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,      3,  3,  3,      4,  4,  4, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,      1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,      3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,      5, 
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5, 5
};
```

### Challenge

The challenge is to write a "reasonably fast" function or expression that replaces and extends these lookup tables.
Think of the lookup tables as a 3D structure.
Pictured is the top 720 boxes of this structure.

[image: challenge]

### Input

An integer which is the index of a cube in the structure.
You can assume the input will be in the range 0 to 719 inclusive.

### Output

The x,y,z coordinates for the given index.
Assuming the input is between 0 and 719 the output ranges are
    x, 0 to 13
    y, 0 to 27
    z, 0 to 8

It's fine to accept and return larger indexes correctly just not required.

### Examples

```
    i  ->   x   y   z
    0  ->   0,  0,  0
   12  ->   0,  5,  1
   30  ->   4,  8,  0
   65  ->   2, 11,  1
  100  ->   0, 13,  2
  270  ->   1, 19,  3
  321  ->   1, 20,  6
  719  ->   1, 27,  8
```

If you collapse the z-coordinate, then the structure is indexed top-down left right like shown below; Examples are marked in square brackets []

```
Y,Z 0,
 0   | [0]  
 1   |  1 
 2   |  2   3 
 3   |  4   5 
 4   |  6   7   8                                1,
 5   |  9  10  11                                 |[12]                           2,
 6   | 13  14  15  16                             | 17                             | 18 
 7   | 19  20  21  22                             | 23  24                         | 25 
 8   | 26  27  28  29 [30]                        | 31  32                         | 33  34 
 9   | 35  36  37  38  39                         | 40  41  42                     | 43  44 
10   | 45  46  47  48  49  50                     | 51  52  53                     | 54  55  56                    3,
11   | 57  58  59  60  61  62                     | 63  64 [65] 66                 | 67  68  69                     | 70                4,
12   | 71  72  73  74  75  76  77                 | 78  79  80  81                 | 82  83  84  85                 | 86                 | 87 
13   | 88  89  90  91  92  93  94                 | 95  96  97  98  99             [100] 101 102 103                |104 105             |106 
14   |107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114             |115 116 117 118 119             |120 121 122 123 124             |125 126             |127 128 
15   |129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136             |137 138 139 140 141 142         |143 144 145 146 147             |148 149 150         |151 152 
16   |153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161         |162 163 164 165 166 167         |168 169 170 171 172 173         |174 175 176         |177 178 179        5,
17   |180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188         |189 190 191 192 193 194 195     |196 197 198 199 200 201         |202 203 204 205     |206 207 208         |209    6, 
18   |210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219     |220 221 222 223 224 225 226     |227 228 229 230 231 232 233     |234 235 236 237     |238 239 240 241     |242     |243 
19   |244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253     |254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 |262 263 264 265 266 267 268     |269[270]271 272 273 |274 275 276 277     |278 279 |280
20   |281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 |292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 |300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 |308 309 310 311 312 |313 314 315 316 317 |318 319 |320[321]
  X->|  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 |  0   1   2   3   4 |  0   1   2   3   4 |  0   1 |  0   1
```

Note that at even y-coordinates the structure expands in the x-direction,
and at 0 and 5 mod 6 in the z-direction.
Expect for the very top block.

## Rules

This is code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

**Reasonably fast**
As an additional requirement although not a competition of fastest code,
the code must still be shown to compute coordinates in a reasonable amount of time.
You may for example use try it online and run a loop through all coordinates under 720 without exceeding the time limit of a minute, printing is optional.

If you fail this rule, mark your answer with non competing

"storing information as you go" is forbidden.
For example executing f(100) should not depend on having computed f(99) previously.

Lookup tables are allowed but included in bytecount so aim to make them sparse if you choose to use them.

## Example code

**non-competing**

```
coord coords(int index){
int a=0,b=0,c=0;
int x=0,y=0,z=0;
long n,k,one;  
n = k = 3;
int t=0;
while(t<index){
int s=0;k++;n=k;
while(n>1 && s<4){ n/=n&-n;n=n*3+1; n/=n&-n;s++;}
if(s==2)t++;
}
n=k; 
one=n&-n;k = one;while(k>1){k>>=1;c++;} n=3*n+one;
one=n&-n;k = one;while(k>1){k>>=1;b++;} n=3*n+one;
one=n&-n;k = one;while(k>1){k>>=1;a++;} 
coord r;
r.x = (b-c-1)>>1;
r.y = a-5;
r.z = (a-b-2)/6 +(a-b-4)/6;
return r;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJNboMwEIX3OcWIqhEESEOStgtjn6QbMJBYpEMERuVHnD0d45JWXVVFjGV/fm9mZFuGJylvDwrlpc1yiBudqWp7FivdX/MsL6DRdSs1yKqqMxgVauiCPhjYZBG72Z15bFyzrzDLO29cAX1mnfBdkFJIvmN32BHoKYYFXio8AQZlUGHOAGaGwKGkOHz79KL/OKtL7ur4d7WGBKXvM@TlTyGKCNZraOKjNwI@cVyHSBrcHPyI3UFDxsmmKtyG872niczAYpPV9kZtWo9p0PRs65Qi8sZSCB4xaZKR47BB3wj@aEv/Z0tm2yy2N1JbZ73tyOKmoQwjT4hooT3RJHxeloMRJWEa7r2nF/Dn6ZGmX/u5bms0KaebOeT3RKFLh36vdG114zoKQgEd9DA4HlsVVW3fA92IiuF1vwOmfJ9sNRVbHgwJrzXJCtd5zIyfxvl/QydQAbVP0VMMpJyo/ic)

Comment: Will the input always be between 0 and 321 (inclusive)?

Comment: Good question, let's go with 797 @streetster

Comment: @streetster 719.. i counted the boxes wrong, good thing I began in the sandbox

Answer (score 1):

## Decode a RISC-V J-type immediate

[RISC-V](https://riscv.org/) is an open processor instruction set, which defines a somewhat typical RISC instruction set. However, in order to make decoding simpler in hardware, the encoding for immediate values tends to be quite complex, with the bits essentially shuffled around. And the worst offender for that is without a doubt the type J (jump) instruction type.

So, the challenge is, given a (non-compressed) RISC-V instruction word, decode and output its type J immediate part.

A type J instruction has the following format:

```
   31      30-21     20       19-12   11-7  6-0
|imm[20]|imm[10:1]|imm[11]|imm[19:12]| rd |opcode|
```

The only fields we are interested in are the `imm` fields. The immediate is sign extended, and its least significant bit is always 0, so the immediate (in term of instruction bits) is:

```
    31-20       19-12       11        10-1     0
|...inst[31]|inst[19:12]|inst[20]|inst[30:21]| 0 |
```

Sample pseudocode: `0xFFF00000 * ((instr >> 31) & 1) | (instr & 0x000FF000) | ((instr & 0x100000) >> 9) | ((instr & 0x7FE00000) >> 20)`.

### Test cases

```
I: 0x4DFAB06F (j 0xABCDE)
O: 0x000ABCDE

I: 0xFD9FF0EF (jal ra, -0x28)
O: 0xFFFFFFD8

I: 0x8000006F (j -0x100000)
O: 0xFFF00000
```

The answer with the smallest byte count wins, standard loopholes apply, etc... Your program may take input and write output in any format it requires.

Comment: It took a bit of puzzling to figure out the second code block. The `...` notation is liable to misunderstanding (I'm not sure whether JS developers would find it more or less confusing), and there's no clear reason for `10-5` and `4-1` to be split up. This is one case where a reference implementation in generic C-like pseudocode could help: I think `0xfff00000 * ((imm >> 31 & 1)) | (imm & 0x000ff000) | ((imm & 0x00100000) >> 9) | ((imm & 0x7fe00000) >> 20)` is correct and fairly generic. (In particular, I've deliberately avoided making assumptions about how the sign bit is treated under `>>`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I copied the instruction format diagram from the RISC-V specification and I didn't realize the 10-5 and 4-1 parts could be merged. Oops. And I added a pseudocode for the decoding.

Answer (score 1):

## Alphanumeric Line and Curve Counting

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188441/alphanumeric-line-and-curve-counting).

Answer (score 1):

### [Bits and Bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57204/programming-with-bits-and-bytes) constant generation

In this challenge, you have to generate the shortest Bits and Bytes program that outputs an integer input. For the simplicity of the challenge, you only have to search with `!` and `<`.

### Bits and Bytes quick reference

Bits and Bytes operates on a one-byte accumulator. There are 4 operations (only 2 are neccecary for this challenge):

- `!` : Invert all of the bits in the accumulator
- `<` : Shifts all bits in the accumulator one bit to the right. The leftmost bit becomes a 0 and the rightmost bit is discarded.
- `>` : Shift right
- `@` : Swap nybbles

### Input / Output

Input will be two integers. The first integer sets the accumulator to the value of that integer. The second integer indicates the resulting value. Your program should output the shortest program in Bits and Bytes that sets the accumulator to that value.

### Examples

```
0
255
!
```

```
0
4
!<!<!<
```

### This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest program wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)

Comment: I'd recommend having the question be self contained and explaining what the instructions actually do

Comment: This is similar enough to some previous challenges that I wouldn't be surprised if someone finds a dupe. Also, should there be a second input for the starting value of the accumulator?

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## WANTEDM?VEMENTANDACALMCOURSE?FE???UENCE

### Challenge

Inspired by puzzles appearing on my [website's chat](http://www.randomstuffonline.com/chat.html), your job (should you choose to accept it) is to accept a string (say `(?@Nbgkx¨¾ÃÐÕã÷øĆĊċĎďěĨīĺŏšŴŹǣǩǮ˘͵ΖΫΰξρφ`) and:

- Find the Unicode points for the string: `[40, 63, 64, 78, 98, 103, 107, 120, 168, 190, 195, 208, 213, 227, 247, 248, 262, 266, 267, 270, 271, 283, 296, 299, 314, 335, 353, 372, 377, 483, 489, 494, 728, 885, 918, 939, 944, 958, 961, 966]`
- Find the differences between elements: `[23, 1, 14, 20, 5, 4, 13, 48, 22, 5, 13, 5, 14, 20, 1, 14, 4, 1, 3, 1, 12, 13, 3, 15, 21, 18, 19, 5, 106, 6, 5, 234, 157, 33, 21, 5, 14, 3, 5]`
- For every element in the differences between elements:

  - If the element is less than 27, add it by 64 and output it converted to a Unicode character (e.g. 1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", \$\ldots\$ ).
  - If the element is greater than or equal to 27, output a non-alphabet character (`[^A-Za-z]`)

### Test Cases

The test cases output in uppercase and use the question mark for the non-alphabet character.

```
(?@Nbgkx¨¾ÃÐÕã÷øĆĊċĎďěĨīĺŏšŴŹǣǩǮ˘͵ΖΫΰξρφ --> WANTEDM?VEMENTANDACALMCOURSE?FE???UENCE
!1CRYkly¤´ÉãýĉĎġĢİĴķņŊŏŖťűŷ --> PROGRAM?PUZZLESANDCODEGOLF
!$37<CR^deswz¤«®¶·ÃÏÔâéîā --> CODEGOLFANDC?GCHALLENGES
!5=BShqt¢¹ÇÍÜôþēĠİĵĹňŞţŵƉƑƖƢƣƽǖǚǩǰȃ -> THEQUIC?WNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOGS
```

### Notes

- The difference between the Unicode points for the string will always be greater than 0.
- The input's Unicode points will be strictly increasing.
- You may output in lowercase.
- The non-alphabet character does not need to be consistent.

Comment: I suggest using less than or equal to 26, so that `Z` can be represented

Comment: @wastl Yeah, done

Comment: What stops us from just adding 97 to all the differences, since outside that range is non-alphabetical?

Comment: @JoKing Nothing stops you from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an idea for a coding challenge, but I'm a). not 100% certain it's not already been done, and b) not sure if some of the golfing specific languages will trivialise it too much.

Basically the premise is thus:

The scoring for your question is achieved in the following fashion:

1. All comments are removed from your script
2. +1 point per character in your script
3. +1 point per character in your output
4. The following algorithm applied to the concatonation of your script and your output:

   - +1 point the first time a character shows up
   - -1 point the second time a character shows up
   - -2 points the third time
   - -4 points the fourth time
   - -8 points the fifth
   - double ad infinitum
5. The scores for character repetition above are cumulative. So, `a` would yield 2 points (1 for length, 1 for first occurance of character). `aa` would yield 2 points (2 for length, +1 for first instance, -1 for second instance). `aaa` would yield 1 point (3 for length, +1 for 1st, -1 for 2nd, -2 for third)

Rules:

- No standard loopholes

I'm also not even sure what I would tag this question as.

Comment: As far as tagging goes: [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: One issue is I could just write a comment with 65,000 unicode characters in it.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms ah so there needs to be a rule excluding comments

Comment: Hmm and I also need a creative way to say “script cannot simply be `print ‘abcdefg...’`

Comment: @Scoots Well, that's where it gets complicated. This could also be considered a [tag:code-bowling] challenge in a way, since the goal is to make the longest source code (or output) possible. The issue with code bowling questions is that they often have exploitable loopholes like comments, regexes, variable names, etc. I'd find a way to work this into the scoring, such as reducing points for source code lengths and adding points for output length

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms that falls afoul of a for loop and a given language’s chr function. This will take some thinking.

Comment: @Scoots Maybe base it on some other element, like execution time?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Nah that's too contingent on circumstances outside our control (how busy is the server when it runs the script etc)... I'm going to think on this for a while. Maybe something creative with exclusives between script and output

Comment: @Scoots I haven't seen too many good posts based on getting the _longest_ source code/output, and I'll be excited to see something new. Good luck!

Comment: I only see a scoring system, but no challenge. Also, in languages like Unary or Whitespace it would be trivial to get arbitrarily large negative scores - and in most languages you can add effective no-ops. I think this kind of thing has been tried before, but it may not have made it past the sandbox because it has big problems which can't really be fixed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The challenge would be to get the highest possible positive score of course, but sadly my thinking has led me to concur with the rest of your statement. Sandbox being the filter it is supposed to be :)

Answer (score 1):

This puzzle is based on [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3261079/3392).

Assume I have some number of black shirts and some number of white shirts, both at least 1. Both colors of shirt have a non-zero durability. All shirts of a given color start with the same durability.

Every day, I pick out a clean shirt to wear, and it becomes dirty. Once I run out of all clean black shirts or all clean white shirts, I wash all my dirty shirts of both colors and start over. Clean shirts do not get washed. Whenever a shirt gets washed, its durability goes down by one. Immediately after washing, if the durability of a shirt reaches 0, it must be thrown out.

When picking which shirt to wear of a particular color, I always choose a shirt with the highest durability of that color to ensure even wear and tear among shirts.

## Challenge:

Take in a sequence of two characters of arbitrary length (eg. b b b w b w w b...) representing my choice of shirt to wear on that day. Continue execution until either my last black shirt or my last white shirt is thrown out. Once this occurs, stop consuming input and halt execution immediately. Note that the program must not consume any more input than is required before halting.

### Inputs:

Number of black shirts, number of white shirts, durability of black shirts, durability of white shirts, and an arbitrary number of two single characters, your choice (eg. b and w)

### Output

None. The program must simply halt when the last shirt of either color is thrown away.

### Test cases

```
1 1 1 1 b

1 999 1 999 b

1 999 1 999 w w w w w w w w b

2 999 1 999 b w w w b

2 999 2 999 b w w w b w b w w w b

5 3 6 1 w w w w w b b b b b b b b b b b b b b w
```

## General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Default input rules apply for the first four arguments. For the arbitrarily long input sequence after the first four arguments, input must come from a source which can provide input one character or byte at a time, of theoretically infinite length, such as STDIN or some other stream.

Comment: How exactly are you going to test that only a certain amount of input has been used?

Comment: Typically you should address concerns made in Sandbox *before* posting to main.

Answer (score 1):

## Calculate mobile data coverage

### Background

You've been hired by the HQ of Vodafizon - a relatively new mobile network provider interested in spreading to the global market. In particular, your job description involves working as a marketing rep to produce ads for each country, where you give a figure of the data coverage, as a percentage, in that country. You get this data from the data scientists, but you've started to notice a pattern: the number always seems to be 98%, 99% or 100% (which, in your experience, seems to be far too high). Despite your trust in Vodafizon, you seem to find this suspicious, so you write your own program to investigate, ensuring maximum precision, even implementing your own floating-point and circle rasterization algorithm to minimize error. You end up making a 112KB monster of a program, but the result confirms your suspicions: these figures are, for the most part, made up by the data scientists, to try and exaggerate their claims.

When you mention this discovery to a coworker, they act surprised at first, but later tell you to keep quiet: upper management probably know about the forgery, and in fact endorse it. Telling them that you know their dirty secret <s>could</s> will result in losing your job.

But here's the thing: you know that advertising these fake numbers could result in massive lawsuits to Vodafizon, the effects of which could result in you getting laid off. You know you can't risk getting fired, but just using the data scientists' figures could be disastrous in the long term.

After consulting Workplace SE, you come up with a plan: keep using your program, but hide it from your superiors. The only issue is, that the data scientists responsible for providing you the data also happen to be the makeshift sysadmins in Vodafizon HQ, so your program can't attract too much attention to itself. 112KB is far more than Vodafizon uses on average (they prefer to split code into lots of tiny files), so when filtering through by file type, the sysadmins will easily see this file as potentially twenty times larger than all the others. So clearly, you need to compress it, without sacrificing the accuracy.

### Input

The input will consist of a nested array of form `[[x, y], [x, y]]` (or alternatively an object of form `[{"x":x, "y":y}, {"x":x, "y":y}]`) of line segments, in clockwise order, defining the border of a country.

The input will also contain a nested array of form `[[x, y, strength], [x, y, strength]]` (or an object of form `[{"x":x, "y":y, "s":strength}, {"x":x, "y":y, "s":strength}]`), which will describe the location of the mobile data towers, and the strength: the radius (or diameter, you can request either in your answer (but not both)) of the circle in which that given tower provides mobile data.

### Output

Your program should output an **approximation** of the mobile data coverage of the input given. Of course, this is impossible to get perfect ([unless you live in Indiana, that is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill)), so you need to provide an approximation, but while reducing your byte count as much as possible. Note that your program **must halt** by itself before 5 seconds of runtime (for any test where the number of towers is less than or equal to 500, and the number of edges is less than 100), or alternatively continuously provide output such that once it is stopped after 5 seconds, the last output will be taken as the result.

### Scoring

Like I mentioned, my program also needs to be small, therefore size will factor into the equation. So, to score your program:

- Get the number of bytes, B
- Run your code with the randomly-generated test cases provided by `tests.py` in this repo, and save the `ref` outputted.
- Run your outputs through `score.py`, providing the `ref` at the start. The last input you will be asked for will be B.

Get the score outputted by `score.py`, and post it in your answer.

## Sandbox

- Is my background too long?
- Is my scoring system too long-winded? I intend to use a complex algorithm (which I have mentally worked out, but not coded yet) which essentially creates a weighted average of all of the scores as a percentage of a value which is correct to 16 decimal places. Is referring people to some code, instead of telling them the algorithm, standard practice? I don't want to spend ages describing a confusing algorithm, when I could just write a program to do it.
- Is this challenge not a duplicate? Is is unclear in any way?

Answer (score 1):

tags: "code-golf", "ellipse", "geometry"

> ### Sandbox Questions
>
> Is this a proper code-golf question?
>
> A major challenge is: How to verify the computed shape? Numerical verification is impossible, since there are infinitely many possible solutions. Is there an easy way to plot xy-data online, or should I provide a script myself? Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.
>
> #### edit:
>
> after 3 days of being posted here in the sandbox, I still have no clear answer to the above question. I therefore propose to ask participants to include their own plot in the answer, which they can make with whatever plotting tool they wish. If people feel inclined to cheating, they only fool themselves, don't they?

## Introduction

To create a circle you can stick a nail in a piece of board, put a loop of string around it and hold it taut with a pencil at the other end. Move the pencil and you get a circle. If you put the loop of string around two nails and move your pencil, you create an ellipse. But what happens if you use three nails, or four, or ten perhaps? It's gonna get ugly soon if you try this in real life, and that's where computers come in handy.

## Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function that accepts **two inputs**:

- A list of (x,y) coordinates (viz. the nails), of arbitrary length>2.
- The length of the rope.

And produces the following **output**:

- A list of coordinates of the poly-oval, which could be fed to a plotting-tool. Plotting the output does not need to be part of your program!

### References

- A graphical example can be found here: [Robert Dickau](https://www.robertdickau.com/oval.html)
- Some handy math on ellipses: [ambrsoft](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circles2/Ellipse/Ellipse.htm)

### Details:

- You may assume that the input coordinates form a convex shape (no inner points on which your program could crash).
- As coordinates, you can use tuples, pairs, complex numbers or even two separate scalars if you like.
- The output resolution (ie. the length of the list) is not so important, but is should give a fair representation of the real curve. In my experience, you'll need between 100 and 1000 points. For smaller rope lengths, you need an even higher resolution.

### Rules and scoring:

- This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes for each language wins.
- Standard rules and default I/O rules apply.
- Loopholes forbidden (of course).

## Example Input and Output

Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.

Input can be any of the following:

> P = [2+0j, -2+1j, -2-1j]
>
> P = [(2,0),(-2,1),(-2,-1)]
>
> X = [2,-2,-2] and Y = [0,1,-1]

Output should be in one of the following forms:

> [0.862+1.591j, 0.703+1.668j, 0.527+1.729j, ...]
>
> [(0.862,1.591), (0.703,1.668), (0.527,1.729), ...]
>
> X = [0.862, 0.703, 0.527, ...], Y = [1.591, 1.668, 1.729, ...]

Comment: "You may assume that the input coordinates form a concave shape" I think you mean *convex*. This is a very helpful assumption though, as you would otherwise need to calculate the convex hull before doing anything interesting.

Comment: "How to verify the computed shape?" - Two possibilities:  1. don't worry about it and make this a graphical output challenge ; 2. specify a starting angle and angle step and require accuracy to within 2 decimal points. ... I personally would go with #1

Comment: @Beefster Thank you, I did indeed mean convex. As per your second comment, frankly I am not interested in how to write short plotting code, I am interested in the  calculation itself. But thanks a lot for your help, I think I will post in a couple of days:)

Comment: One solution would be to specify a pixel resolution and require that the density of output points should be sufficient that the maximum separation between the curve and the piecewise linear output should be half a pixel. Then you can compare the output with the output of a reference implementation by looking for separations of more than one pixel.

Answer (score 1):

### Broken mouse

This is just an idea, I have not elaborated it.

My mouse accidentally fell to the ground, and now there is a double click for each of my single click(which makes window-closing very hard to do). :(

Most computer screens have a higher resolution ratio than 16x12, but let's assume that my computer screen has a 16x12 resolution ratio.

Example: A Window looks like this:

```
0-----OX
|      |
--------
```

The number 0 is the indicator of the window. `O` is a dragging button that allows windows to be moved. `X` is a closing button that closes the window. (You can not resize windows.)
Assume that there is a window below that window looking like this:

```
1-----OX
|      |
--------
```

If I click X, I will close both windows. However, what should(or must, if appropriate) I do if I only want to close the first window?

I can move my mouse to the `O` tab and drag the window around by using mousedown. After 1 drag to the right:

```
10-----OX
||      |
---------
```

Now I can click the `X` to close the window 0 after I click the `O` button again to remove the dragging effect. (Note that there is the window "1" below that window.)

Wait, I changed my mind and wanted to close the window 1. What should I do?

I should click the number 1; then, the window 1 goes to the top and the `X` button shows. Now I can click the X button to close the 1 window.

For reference, this is the TUI commands I used(when the mouse starts at 0x0):

```
0-----O
>>>>>>.>.<<<<<<<.>>>>>>.
```

What should I do if I want to close the windows that I specified? (Output the TUI instructions.) (Your score is -(code length + output); you want to keep your score as high as possible.)

### TUI Instructions

- `^v<>`: Move the mouse up, down, left, or right
- `.`: Mouse down+mouse up (i.e. click)

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Output for what (set of) input?

Comment: @The Obviously a list of coordinates of the input windows...

Comment: Is this always possible? If the frontmost window is as large as the screen, by dragging the "O" you cannot make the lower-leftmost cell appear. What if the "X" of the desired window is there?

Comment: I guess I will make the windows draggable for at least 1 direction and at most 4 directions. (The window is always smaller than the screen.)

Comment: Oh I see, otherwise output impossible to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1):

## I mainly need help with scoring as I want to encourage use of esolangs.

I also would like to know how to improve the answer-ability of this question in languages that don't specifically have defined functions

---

## Church booleans

A [church boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) is a function that returns `x` for true and `y` for false where `x` is the first argument to the function and `y` is the second argument to the function. Further functions can be composed from these functions which represent the `and` `not` `or` and `xor` logical operations.

## Challange

Construct the church booleans and `and` `not` `or` and `xor` church gates in a language of your choice.

## Scoring

The total length of all of the code required to make church true and false in your language and the `and` `not` `or` and `xor` church gates excluding the functions name. (for example, `false=lambda x,y:y` in python would be 12 bytes). You can reuse these names later in your code.

## Pseudo code Examples:

```
true(x, y) -> x
false(x, y) -> y
and(true, true)(x, y) -> x
and(true, false)(x, y) -> y
# ... etc
```

Comment: instead of functions, you should also accept full programs. I also don't understand what your examples represent(is `and` supposed to be a curried function?)

Comment: @SuperStormer `and` returns a church boolean which is a function which is then called with variables `x` and `y` and returns `x` or `y` based on whether that function is the true or false church boolean. In the examples I was just trying to get across the nature of church gates and church booleans without answering the question. I wanted to break it up into discrete functions for readability and to ensure that the question is actually being answered correctly

Comment: I'm not really sure it's possible to make this work for all languages, except by just operating on lambda calculus expressions with no actual significance within the language, but that aside you definitely don't need anything additional to encourage esolangs on this site!

Comment: @UnrelatedString as far as fit for this site goes do you think there is anything I should add to improve the question?

Comment: Esoteric languages usually don't support function as first-order object very well, but they usually have `eval` so it may work using some "function" representation.

Comment: Otherwise I don't think there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf) [rubiks-cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)

## Solve All the Rubik's Cubes!

I want to solve a Rubik's Cube. Unfortunately, I am blind, and my friend doesn't know how to solve a Rubik's Cube, so I just make one move at a time and ask my friend if it is solved. This generally doesn't work very well, so I would like to know a specific thing I could do to increase my chances of eventually fixing it. Also, I don't like memorizing things, so please keep your solution as short and simple as possible.

### Rules

- I cannot see the cube or anything about it.
- The only thing my friend will tell me about the cube is whether or not it is solved.
- My friend and I are fully willing to wait until the heat death of the universe to solve this, if necessary.
- I don't have a great memory, so keep your instructions as short as possible.
- I can feel around the cube enough to turn whatever face you tell me to turn in whatever direction.
- I can turn the cube in my hands.
- I can memorize anything you give me, but I won't like it.

### Solution Format

Give me a description of turns to do on my Rubik's Cube, to be repeated endlessly (or until I solve it).

```
F: Turn the front face clockwise
B: Turn the back face clockwise
R: Turn the right face clockwise
L: Turn the left face clockwise
U: Turn the top face clockwise
D: Turn the top face clockwise

x: Turn the cube so the top face becomes the front
y: Turn the cube so the left face becomes the front
z: Turn the cube so the left face becomes the top
```

`'` can be appended to any of these commands to make them go in the opposite direction.

Also, to make things easier, you can give me inner repetitions. Write these as

```
{...commands...}*4
```

where `4` is the number of times it is repeated. Inner repetitions can be nested.

### Scoring

Non-memorability:

- Each turn gives one point.
- For nested repetitions, double the point value of everything inside the repetition and add the number of times I do it.

Effectiveness:

- Any sequence of moves on a Rubik's cube will eventually return to the initial state. The effectiveness is how many turns are required before this happens (roughly equivalent to how many states it passes through).

Total score = non-memorability / effectiveness

Solutions that are easier to remember are probably better than solutions that are hard to remember but will be solved.

Lowest total score wins.

> ### Questions:
>
> - Will people actually answer this question?
> - Is the specification clear enough?
> - This is my first question. Is there anything else I need to consider before posting?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, however it may actually be a better fit for https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/. Either way, it's not entirely clear what the end goal is; Am I trying to find the series of moves that will make it *likely* for the cube to be solved *quickly* (on heatdeath timescale), or am I looking for a series of moves that garuntees it will be solved eventually? Also see (similar but not duplicates I'm pretty sure) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694536/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184760/

Comment: I'm looking for something easy to remember, with a reasonable chance of eventually solving it. This doesn't have a definite answer and should focus more on space optimization (golfing) (the existing Hamiltonian Circuit is probably very difficult to remember and would score poorly), so it might not fit as well on Puzzling.

Comment: As written, I agree with Shelvacu that this is for puzzling. This is still a programming site, so here it would be better to ask for a program to output the solution. But that's probably necessary anyway, given that the fully expanded solution will have at *least* 43.252.003.274.489.855.999 moves.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually, it would most likely be between 34,326,986,725,785,600 and 43,251,683,287,486,463,996. This is basically the Devil's Algorithm: [_a set of moves that when applied, repeatedly if necessary, will eventually return a Rubik's Cube to a solved state regardless of the starting configuration_](http://anttila.ca/michael/devilsalgorithm/#targetText=Definition%3A%20A%20Devil's%20Algorithm%20is,in%20the%20shortest%20Devil's%20Algorithm.).

Answer (score 1):

### Talk interpreter

"Talk" is a baroquified accumulator-based language that is created in order to make it difficult to put on Try It Online. The "Talk" language has 4 commands:

- `00` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 0.
- `01` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 1.
- `10` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 0.
- `11` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 1.

### Input:

- The input can be taken via any acceptable input method by our standard I/O rules.
- The input will always be a sequence of the commands above.
- The program will take an input that is either 1 or 0 to set the accumulator to.

### Output:

- On the end of a command execution, the accumulator is outputted implicitly.

### Rules:

- The input has to be a single string or character list, and splitting it in parts of size 2 is part of the challenge.
- As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer, in bytes, wins.

  ---

  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

Comment: So we take two inputs? The starting `0`/`1`, and the sequence of commands? Since you state I/O is flexible, would for the commands a list of 2-character strings be allowed (i.e. `["00","01","11","11","01"]`)? Or does the input have to be a single string or character list, and splitting it in parts of size 2 is part of the challenge?

Comment: Um, commands `00` and `11` don't seem to do anything, while the other two seem to be just 'set the accumulator to 0/1'

Comment: The commands ```00``` and ```11``` was added in order to avoid uninteresting abuses like directly printing the last character of the code.

Comment: Why would this be difficult to put on Try It Online? Does the accumulator ever do any accumulating?

Comment: This will overlap with the existing talk.tryitonline.net.

Comment: Um, it's not that hard to change the name slightly. Languages like `><>`, `///` and `???` already have url friendly names

Comment: Do you know how to change the name "Talk" slightly?

Comment: @Shelvacu, I imagine that it would be difficult to persuade Dennis that a "language" this useless is worth space on his server.

Answer (score 1):

## Distant Programs

Create a program that, when run, prints "Do you still love me?" with or without a newline at the end.

Your score is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to the closest non-erroring program (the non-erroring program doesn't have to do anything, although it might), and you want the largest score. Ties are broken by whichever code is shorter, in bytes.

Your program *can* read it's own source code, through the filesystem or otherwise. If your program must have a specific name, the length of that name should be included in your byte count.

Notes:

- Compiler warnings are not counted as errors for this challenge.
- An erroring program can output, frobricate, do anything as long as it eventually errors.

---

Notes for the sandbox:

- Is the specification clear?
- Is it possible to create a solution that can simply be repeated to get any arbitrary score? If so it would pretty much ruin the challenge as it is, and I think it should be possible but I can't get it to work.
- What tags would this use?

Comment: I think it should be possible to get arbitrary scores using quining techniques and cryptographic hash verification.

Comment: In addition to what Peter said, I think there is a clarity problem in defining precisely what counts as an error.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I was going top copy my definition of "error" from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/ but to my surprise there isn't one. Honestly I'm not sure how exactly to define "error".

Answer (score 1):

### Normalized Malbolge to Malbolge translator

In this task, you will write a program/function that takes a Normalized Malbolge program and outputs the resulting Malbolge program. (This is a secret tool that all Malbolge programmers are using!)

### Input

A data structure that (somehow) represents a Normalized Malbolge program.

### Output

A data structure that represents the resulting Malbolge program.

### Examples

```
jpoo*pjoooop*ojoopoo*ojoooooppjoivvvo/i<ivivi<vvvvvvvvvvvvvoji:
(=BA#9"=<;:3y7x54-21q/p-,+*)"!h%B0/.~P<<:(8&66#"!~}|{zyxwvugJ%

jjjj*<jjjj*<v
('&%#^"!~}{XE

jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj*<jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj*<v
('&%$#"!~}|{zyxwvutsrqpnKmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVT1|
```

### How to convert

This is a placeholder for the convertion process.

```
def normal_to_malbolge(prog):
    pos = 0
    malbolge = ""
    for i in prog:
        char = ord("' ( > D Q b c u".split()["*jpovi</".find(i)]) - pos
        while char < 33:
            char += ord("~")-32
        malbolge += chr(char)
        pos += 1
    return malbolge
```

#### Explanation

Iterate over the normalized Malbolge program, and then convert all `"*jpovi</"`'s to a character in `"'", '(', '>', 'D', 'Q', 'b', 'c', 'u'`. Then, minus the position.

While the temporary Malbolge representations' ASCII code is less than 33, increment the char by the ASCII code of "~" minus 32.

Append the resulting character to the output.

### Rules

- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer wins.
- No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) please.
- The default I/O methods are allowed.

  ### Sandbox
- Is it a duplicate? This probably is.
- Is the challenge well-written?

Comment: You need to include the instructions for converting normalized malbolge to malbolge (will give later)

Comment: ^ Check my code to convert and make an explanation out of that. Some people don't know python, and my code is very ugly

Comment: You could include a link to the standard loopholes, and put in that default I/O methods are allowed. Other than that I /support

Answer (score 1):

## I need help rewording the prompt.

I learned from last time about having convoluted scoring and having too broad of a focus from my [last question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190325/church-booleans). I hope this one is more clear.

## Church Subtraction

Lambda calculus has always been a fascination of mine and the emergent behaviors of passing functions into each other is delightfully complex. [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals) are representations of natural numbers contructed from the repeated application of a function (normally the unary addition of a constant). For example, the number zero returns and "ignores" the input function, one is `f(x)`, two is `f(f(x))` and so on:

```
ident = lambda x: x
zero = lambda f: ident
succ = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
one = succ(zero)
add1 = lambda x: x + 1
to_int = lambda f: f(add1)(0)
print(to_int(one))
>>> 1
```

From this we can easily see that addition is accomplished by applying the first function to x then applying the second function to x:

```
add = lambda m: lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: n(f)(m(f)(x))
print(to_int(add(one)(two)))
>>> 3
```

Addition is relatively easy to understand. However, to a newcomer it might be inconceivable to think of what subtraction looks like in a Church encoded number system. What could it possibly mean to un-apply a function?

## Challenge

Implement the subtraction function in a Church encoded numeral system. Where subtraction performs the [monus operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus) and unapplies a function `n` times if the result will be greater than zero or zero otherwise. This is code-golf so shortest code wins.

## Input

Two Church numerals that have been encoded in your choice of language. The input can be positional or curried. To prove these are true Church numerals they will have to take in any function and apply them repeatedly (`add1` is given in the examples but it could be `add25`, `mult7`, or any other unary function.)

## Output

A Church numeral. It should be noted that if `m < n` then `m - n` is always the same as the identity function.

Examples:

```
minus(two)(one) = one
minus(one)(two) = zero
...
```

also acceptable:

```
minus(two, one) = one
minus(one, two) = zero
```

Credit:

This [github gist](https://gist.github.com/vivekhaldar/2438498) for giving me a python implementation of Church Numerals.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure how to parse "*the number zero is a cat function Church encoding*". Perhaps it would be better expressed as "*the Church encoding of the number zero is the identity function*"? 2. Explaining multiplication is an unnecessary distraction (unlike addition, which is relevant context). You've got a link to Wikipedia for people who want to learn more. 3. There is a technical term, *monus*, which describes the truncated subtraction. The truncation at zero should be described in the Challenge section, not the Output, and you might want to introduce this term there.

Comment: 1. I missed an "in" and a cat function is pretty known in esolangs (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cat_program), thank you for catching this. 2. I could explain exponentiation as well and maybe that might make a more compelling story. Or should I just stick with addition? 3. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: 1. `cat` is well known in POSIX too, and in both cases it does I/O. I think it's misleading and confusing to call `ident` a cat function. And the word order of the edited version is ambiguous, and IMO tends to the parse "*(the number zero) (is) (a cat function in Church encoding)*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor that work better?

Answer (score 1):

## Black And White Shirts 3

This is the third in a series. The first can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/189515/73483), and the second [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/189531/73483). The premise is similar to the first two, but with some changes and a new goal.

Assume I have some number of black shirts and some number of white shirts, both at least 1. Both colors of shirt have a non-zero Vividness. All shirts of a given color start with the same Vividness.

Every day, I pick out a clean shirt to wear, and it becomes dirty. Once I run out of all clean black shirts or all clean white shirts, I wash all my dirty shirts of both colors and start over. Clean shirts do not get washed. Whenever a shirt gets washed, its color changes based on its Vividness and the Vividness and colors of the other shirts being washed, then its Vividness goes down by one to a minimum of 0. All things being equal, over time, all shirts will generally tend towards a shade of gray.

If a shirt is ever closer to the opposite color (eg. a black shirt looks light gray), it becomes a shirt of that color.

When picking which shirt to wear, I choose the shirt which is either closest to black or closest to white. If there is a tie, I choose the one with the highest Vividness.

## Challenge:

Take in an arbitrarily long sequence of two indicators (eg. b b w w b w b b w b...) representing my choice of shirt to wear on that day. Continue execution until either my last black shirt or my last white shirt loses its last vividness. Once this occurs, stop consuming input and print out the colors of all shirts.

### Inputs:

Number of black shirts, number of white shirts, Vividness of black shirts, Vividness of white shirts, and a sequence of shirt selections of arbitrary length at least long enough for one color of shirt to run out of Vividness (can be considered infinitely long). The selection can be represented by any two characters (eg. b, w).

### Output:

Color of all shirts, sorted from lightest to darkest, as a percent of how close it is to white, rounded to the nearest whole percent. A completely black shirt is 0, and a completely white shirt is 100.

### Color changing:

The color of a shirt tends towards the average of all shirts' colors in the wash. How close it gets depends on its own Vividness.

TODO: Determine if this rule is necessary (I don't think it is): If all shirts in the wash have 0 Vividness, none of them change color.

When washed, shirts are changed based on the following pseudocode algorithm (some of which may not be necessary for your simulation):

```
struct shirt {
    int vividness
    float color
}

func washShirts(shirt[] allDirtyShirts) {
    totalVividness = allDirtyShirts.sum(shirt => shirt.vividness)
    if (totalVividness == 0)
        return

    averageDirtyColor = allDirtyShirts.sum(shirt => shirt.color * shirt.vividness) / totalVividness

    for each shirt in allDirtyShirts
    {
        shirt.color = (shirt.color * shirt.vividness + averageDirtyColor) / (shirt.vividness + 1)
        if shirt.vividness > 0
            shirt.vividness--
        if shirt.isBlack && shirt.color > .5
            shirt.isBlack = false
        else if !shirt.isBlack && shirt.color < .5
            shirt.isBlack = true
    }
}
```

Make sure that all shirts base their calculation on the Vividness and color values of all other shirts *before* the change. Perform no rounding beyond normal floating point restraints within your language of choice (within reason) during any calculation. Only round the value during output. When rounding for output, choose any convenient rounding method among:

- truncating (always round down)
- rounding to the nearest integer

  - .5 rounds up
  - .5 rounds down
  - .5 rounds to the nearest even integer

### Test cases:

Note: These test cases use rounding to the nearest even integer. Your output may vary in some cases.

```
1 2 1 1 w b
100 75 25

3 3 2 1 w b w b w w w w w w w w
71 71 71 14 14 0
#note that processing would stop after w b w b w. The remaining input would be ignored.

#todo: more test cases
```

## General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Default I/O rules apply

Answer (score 1):

## Determine the minimal indices needed to cover all queries

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

This challenge is based on Mongo's handling of [compound indices](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) and [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/), inspired by a problem that came up at work, but I'll restate the relevant details here.

### Background

In any database, relational or not, the primary purpose of indices is to optimize data lookup.

For example, if the task of finding all [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions on this site had to be accomplished by looping through all posts and looking for the `code-golf` tag, it would be unusably slow. An index, however, organizes this data in a way that enables fast and efficient lookup of the data we want, which drastically reduces the resource cost of queries in exchange for some more work and space in maintaining the index.

However, the cost of maintaining indices is not negligible, so it quickly becomes untenable to create 2^N indices for N fields. (Databases designed for this purpose do exist and are the better choice when this functionality is actually needed. I'm ignoring this fact because it's a more interesting challenge this way.) Thus, careful index construction and selection is important to get the most bang for your buck.

### Details

A simple index only organizes data based on one field but Mongo provides two ways to efficiently query on more than one field: compound indices and index intersection.

#### Compound Indices

Compound indices organize data based on a sequence of fields, e.g. `[A, B, C]`. Here, order matters. If data is sorted by `A` then `B` then `C`, then doing a lookup based on `C` first cannot be done efficiently since there are no guarantees on where the desired data might be located within the index (whereas one could do e.g. a binary search based on `A`).

**Note:** compound indices enable efficient queries on *prefixes* of that index as well. That is, a compound index on `[A, B, C]` enables efficient queries that have `[A]`, `[A, B]`, or `[A, B, C]`. However, as previously mentioned, it does not support queries that have `[B]`, `[C]`, `[A, C]`, or `[B, C]`.

#### Index Intersection

Exactly two indices can be used to optimize a query if there does not already exist a compound index for the desired fields. That is, if there is an index on `[A]` and an index on `[B]`, then a query on `[A, B]` can be executed fairly efficiently (though not as efficiently as if there was a compound index, but let's ignore that). This also applies to prefixes of indices, so an index on `[A, B, C]` and an index on `[C]` can be intersected to support a query with `[A, C]`.

### Problem

**Given N fields, determine the minimal indices needed to make all possible queries on those fields efficient.** That is, minimize the total number of fields indexed. There may be more than one minimal set.

**Note:** the order of fields in the *query* doesn't matter since the query analyzer can reorder these fields to be as optimal as possible before running the query.

### Input/Output

Input is a single positive integer and the output should consist of clearly-delimited sequences.

### Examples

*A variety of output formats are shown here to demonstrate what I mean by "clearly-delimited sequences".*

**N: 1**

```
[0]
```

**N: 2**

```
AB
B
```

**N: 3**

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['C']]

['AB', 'BC', 'CA']
```

To elaborate on the first example in this N=3 case, the first index covers a query with all three fields, index intersections cover all choices of two fields, and index prefixes cover all queries with one field.

**Note:** for N=5, the obvious pattern does not hold; the indices `ABCDE BCDE CDE DE E` do not enable an efficient query on `A, C, E`.

---

### Meta

<s>I am *really* hoping this doesn't boil down to `[A, B, ..., X], [B, ..., X], [C, ..., X], ... [X]`. I haven't taken a look at the N=4 case yet though so I don't know if this pattern holds.</s>

Thankfully, the pattern breaks down for N=5.

Answer (score 1):

## N-bonacci from a Seed

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci)

An [N-bonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order) is a Fibonacci-like sequence where the N previous terms are added to get the next term. The Fibonacci series is a 2-bonacci sequence.

Given a list of integers `L` of length `l` and an integer `n`, output the first `n` digits of the `l`-bonacci sequence starting with the sequence `L`.

## Input

Input is a list, array, delimited string, stream, etc of integers, and an integer. Input is flexible, provided `L` and `n` are separable. It is guaranteed that `n >= 0`, and `l >= 1`.

## Output

Output the first `n` digits of the `l`-bonacci sequence starting with `L`. Output is flexible here also: a list, array, string, stream, etc.

Samples:

```
[1,1], 5       --> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5
[0,1,2], 1     --> 0
[10,1,-1], 10  --> 10, 1, -1, 10, 10, 19, 39, 68, 126, 233
[-1,0,1], 0    --> //no output, or empty output
[-1], 3        --> -1, -1, -1
[-1,-2,1,0], 9 --> -1, -2, 1, 0, -2, -3, -4, -9, -15
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest in bytes wins.

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70476/print-the-n-bonacci-sequence)

Comment: You'd probably need to explain what an `l`-bonacci sequence is. That said I'm not sure this isn't a dupe of the related challenge you posted since at least some answers (including mine) would be able to be reposted with `[1]*n` replaced with `L` and `n` replaced with `len(L)`.

Comment: Closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70476/31716

Comment: `n <= l` seems like an odd restriction, which your test cases don't always follow. If that is an actual requirement, this would be `L[:n]` in Python, which I don't think you want.

Comment: Hmm. I'll axe `n <= l` then and change it to `n >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Battleships TDM

In this (not so simple) game of commanding a battleship, you are tasked to defeat the opposing team. Cooperation is essential in order to win the battle.

Each ship starts with $${500\cdot\bigg\lfloor\frac{10}{\log{\frac{n}{3}}}}\bigg\rfloor$$ health (rounded down), where `n` is a number of players. At 30 players, it is 5000.

### Setup

The game starts with a square map of length **50+3n**. On top and bottom there is 15% of the width, in which the players' ships will spawn. The rest of the map will be prodedurally generated with islands.

The sample map looks like this:
[image: Map]

### Phase 1: Issuing commands

On your turn, your program will be given a file `input.txt` located in the program's directory, with following format:

```
TURN=(turn number)
SIZE=(size of the map)
YOUR_SHIP=(first 6 chars from SHA1 hash of your ship's name; in case of conflicts a random one will be generated)
YOUR_TEAM=(your team's id)
HEALTH=(your ship's health)
POS=(position of your ship in 0,0 format)
SPEED=(your ship's speed)
DIR=(your ship's direction)
TERRAIN:
(21x21 square of characters, centered on the ship)
PROXIMITY:
(line-separated list of ships within 10 squares, with its properties separeated by semicolon)
CHAT:
(line-separated history of text sent by teammates from the last and current round)
```

For example:

```
TURN=21
SIZE=110
YOUR_SHIP=acf44a
YOUR_TEAM=1
HEALTH=3231
POS=64,121
SPEED=3
DIR=NW
TERRAIN:
.....................
###.............x....
##.................##
(etc.)
PROXIMITY:
bd439a=1;69,132;S;3 (ship's id, team, position, direction, speed)
43351f=2;78,112;NE;4
(etc.)
CHAT:
58ab38@21: ENEMY_SHIP 582af2 @ 142,62 NE 3
902dd1@20: 033b2c 4 92,62 SW 1
(etc.)
```

The map shows `.` for water, `#` for land, `x` for wrecks, `1` and `2` for ships belonging to particular team.

Your program is allowed **3 actions** per turn. The actions are:

```
NONE - do nothing
TURN_LEFT - rotates ship counterclockwise by 45 degrees
TURN_RIGHT - rotates ship clockwise by 45 degrees
SPEED_UP - increases speed by 1. At speed 5 it is ignored.
SPEED_DOWN - decreases speed by 1. At speed -1 it is ignored. 
MESSAGE=message - sends a message to chat
FIRE=x,y - fire a projectile in specified location. Can be done only once per turn. 
           The cannon has range of 25. Issuing a command which exceeds it is ignored.
```

For example:

```
TURN_LEFT
SPEED_UP
FIRE=62,69
```

must be written to `output.txt`. After each round the file is cleared.

### Phase 2: Movement phase

All ships in random order move forward defined by their speed.

- If ship hits the land or wreck during movement, the ship stops and takes damage worth 50x of ship's speed.
- If ship hits the map border, same situation applies.
- If ship hits other ship, it is considered **ramming**:

  - If rammed from the front, both ships receive damage worth 100x sum of ships' speeds. Both ships stop.
  - If rammed from the back, rammed ship receives damage worth 20x difference of ships' speeds. Rammed ship moves one step forward and ramming ship ends its movement.
  - If rammed from the side, rammed ship receives damage worth 100x speed of ramming ship, while the ramming one receives 50x. Ramming ship stops.
  - If rammed at the angle, rammed ship receives damage worth 50x speed of ramming ship, while the ramming one receives 20x. Ramming ship stops.
  - If the rammed ship is friendly, ramming ship receives 1 point of friendly fire.

### Phase 3: Firing phase

In the same order ships fire from the cannons (if any). If the cannon hits a target:

- That is within range 10: Shots deal 500 + 0-99 damage
- That is beyond range 10: Shots deal 500 + 0-99 damage + 0-99 damage for each unit beyond 10th (up to 2084 total damage at range 25)
- If the target is friendly, the damage is 0 and shooting ship receives 1 point of friendly fire.
- There is 5% chance to make a hit critical: The total damage is tripled and shooter recieves 1 critical point.
- If it is a fatal blow, it is considered a **destruction**:

  - The fatal blow dealer receives a fatal point.
  - Attacker with most dealt damage receives a kill point (it may be the same ship as the dealer).
  - Everyone else with a hit receives an assist point.
  - If it is a solo kill, the dealer receives 2 of each points instead.

### Phase 4: Checking conditions

Each ship is considered a wreck if:

- Health reaches below 0 HP,
- Ship gains 5 friendly fire points.

Wrecks remain on the map, but they are removed from the queue and program of such ships is being not executed.

Game ends whenever entire team gets destroyed or after 1000 turns, in which the points are being calculated as follows:

- 1 point for each 10 damage dealt
- 500 points for each kill
- 200 points for each fatal blow
- 100 points for each assist
- 150 points for each critical hit
- -250 points for each friendly fire hit
- 1000 points for each winning team member
- Points for achievements (names are just for decoration):

```
500 (awarded once) Beyond the horizon - Hit on enemy from 13 sq or more
500 (awarded once) Maximum range - Hit on enemy from 23 sq or more
500 (awarded once per participant) Coordinated attack - 3 or more ships attacking the same target
500 (awarded once) Hammer - Ram a ship on full speed
500 (awarded each time) - Survive a critical hit
1000 (awarded once per participant) Anihilation - Both ships getting destroyed in headfront ramming
```

**The ship with most points after 10 games wins.**

### Code

The controller code is here.

### Rules

Your program **can**:

- store data in files within its own directory
- communicate with teammates through the team's chat

Your program **cannot**:

- read files outside its scope
- disrupt the communications
- Attack friendly ships on purpose
- Copy other competitors' functionality (No duplicates)
- Use [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

### Sandbox questions

- I'm not sure whether to allow the challenge in any usual language or require one specific (in this case Java 8)?
- Wouldn't be achievements unnecessary? If not, could be any added/modified/removed?
- Are there some rules that require clarification?

Comment: What does "procedurally generated with islands" mean? Could you provide a small example map? What does "15% of the width where players' ships spawn" mean? Are they distributed randomly, or packed into a corner (or do they have a choice)?

Comment: @someone 1. "Procedurally generated islands" I meant. 2. Added. 3. Area reserved for ships to spawn. 4. Randomly across the spawn area.

Comment: a) Ship health and *particularly* map size, in my opinion, scale in a weird way with participant count. b) I would *highly* recommend avoiding file I/O in favor of sending data to programs via STDIN and reading their actions via STDOUT. c) Additionally, I would recommend using a ubiquitous I/O format, like JSON or XML. This will reduce the amount of boilerplate code that the participants will have to write. Moreover, it would prevent d) the problem of newlines in chat. e) What order are the programs asked for output in? This is important for chat, for example.

Comment: f) Does the damaging behavior differ depending on whether the ramming ship hit the front-right/left or the back-right/left? g) Does ramming a friendly ship deal damage to it? Please make that clear. h) Does solo-killing also provide 2 assist points? I'm guessing it doesn't, but it's not clear either. i) Shooting right at the current position of an enemy ship seems ridiculously effective. You've got a 50% chance to hit by definition, while all the other methods necessarily have less, since the ship can dodge. I can see very few edge cases. That's just my opinion, however.

Comment: j) I misunderstood the "1000 points for each winning team member" the first 2 times I read it. "1000 points for member of the the winning team" is clearer in my opinion. k) Coordinated attack achievement is perhaps a bit unclear, but I can't seem to put into words why that is. l) 10 games is not an awful lot. While I understand that you don't want to run this for too long, this game does seem to be a bit random. m) Attacking friendly ships "on purpose" is difficult to define rigorously, and is already punished by the game, which makes it Emo Wolf-y. All in all I find the rule unnecessary.

Comment: n) It would be lovely if the challenge was available for all standard languages. I would definitely not participate if it was Java-only. p) How are teams chosen? Randomly every game? r) I *strongly* recommend making a dedicated chat room for participants once the challenge hits main - you seem to be looking forward to coordinated plays, and I don't think they're possible without an agreed-upon communication format, which in turn is unlikely to develop without any group discussion amongst players.

Comment: Correction for j) - I meant "1000 points for each member of the winning team". There's also a general problem of weird English present in all parts of the spec, but as long as it's understandable (which it is), there shouldn't be any problems here. Anyway, looking forward to the updated spec, and of course to the challenge itself. Good luck!

Comment: @Alion The main issue is that I have no idea how can I run programs from multiple languages, so my controller could capture it and interpret all actions within reasonable time (since I'd have to run *each* program *thousands* of times to make an action). I don't want to end up copying/pasting/calculating everything by hand each turn, which could take a week or more to finish the game. The further points will refer to this one as I go

Comment: a) True, but the ship health has at least been addressing the time constraints. I could end up with some long functions for both of those anyway. b) STDIN/OUT capture issue. c) Haven't thought of this. d) Oh? e) What order? I'm not sure what do you mean. f) FL/R and BL/R deal the same damage. g) Uh, yes. h) Would have to think about it. i) Do you suggest any alternatives? l) Time constraints, again. n) Here we go back to the issue with multiple languages. p) Random every game. r) I would if I had the power to do so. Currently I don't. *(BTW English is not my first language)*

Comment: I've cobbled together a simple demo of how a language-agnostic controller could work. As I don't write Java, I used C# instead, but the code should be mostly readable for a Java developer as well. You will certainly need to find the Java equivalents of the methods and classes used, but I would be very surprised if Java doesn't support something akin to what I've done in C# at all. I also assumed Windows all throughout. [Here's a demo.](https://gist.github.com/alion02/1fbdac55a1a06b9ac82a34a644014a14). Contains the C# controller and the files required for a sample Python entry.

Comment: a) After understanding what the ship health function does, I don't have a problem with it anymore. The map size, however, grows quadratically with the ship count. d) You've defined chat as a line-separated history of messages. But what happens if an entry decides to put a newline into its message? e) Are the programs queried for actions in a consistent order? If so, what is the initial order? Random? Additionally, being early in the call order is a huge disadvantage, since most of the messages received will be from the previous turn, as I understand it.

Comment: i) It's really difficult to come up with any alternatives from my position. I don't have access to your vision of the game. Inevitably I end up overhauling the battle system one way or another and remain unsatisfied with it. Considering previous challenges, however, I can't say for sure if this really is a notable flaw.

Comment: Alion's point (b) is addressed at the execution speed issue you raise. See https://github.com/pjt33/ppcg36515 (linked from the KotH tag wiki) for an example which supports Java submissions natively and other languages by stdin/stdout communication. Another issue which Alion has touched on briefly is the team business: it needs to be clear how the teams will be assigned.

Comment: I have slightly edited your equation, feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

## Solve a cubic equation [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(Is this really not a duplicate?)

Comment: Apparently not. I can find multiple quadratic equation challenges: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/resolve-quadratic-equation); [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36127/solve-quadratic-equation-using-only-3-variables-and-arithmetic); [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/solve-a-quadratic-equation-using-vietas-formulas), but there doesn't seem to be any cubic equation challenges yet.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a dupe of either https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154001/194 or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11694/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor The first challenge only asks for integer solutions, while yours has some constraints that this challenge might not have.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, I said "*might*" because "*solve*" is so vague that there's no way of knowing what the challenge is. And I don't think my challenge has constraints so much as licence to not have to be accurate to 1ulp. It's true that cubics can't be as ill-conditioned as higher-order polynomials, but there are still some nasty cases.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think there's a lot of subtleties in specifying challenges like this. I'd really like to push solvers to do something like the cubic formula rather than some generic method to solve or brute-force a polynomial equation. It's also fair that it's hard to judge anything from just a title. I'll try writing something up later and would be happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Regarding Peter's comment about the ambiguity of not including the description, one important thing to include is whether we must at least find one solution, the real solutions, or all solutions (I'm in favor of the last option). Also, "pushing solvers to do work" can be as simple as encouraging them to implement an algorithm that's more than just a built-in solving function (including the built-in solution for reference doesn't hurt, if it exists).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Can you explain why you like the last option of requiring all solutions? I had thought a bit about this and was leaning pretty heavily to only asking for one solution because it gives less advantage to generic solvers (even non built-ins) over writing a formula, and it means one never has to output a complex solution for languages that don't support them natively.

Comment: The "less advantage" restricting the output to one solution gives is simply a need for the answer to just pick one of the solutions it has found, in the worst case. Also, there are some cases where there are only complex solutions. If you want to account for such languages, you will need to add a guarantee that the equation will have at least one real solution, and none of the aforementioned cases will ever be input (there's some ambiguity about this currently).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Doesn't every cubic equation have a real solution? I'm not intending to include ones where the leading coeff is zero so it's really quadratic.

Comment: Hm, must've been thinking of something else (I'm currently doing other stuff). And yeah, a cubic equation \$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\$ is cubic precisely because \$a\ne0\$.

Answer (score 1):

## Randomize \$SL_n(\mathbb R)\$

Given a positive integer \$n > 1\$, return a random element from \$SL_n(\mathbb R)\$.

#### Details

- \$SL_n(\mathbb R)\$ is the set of \$n \times n\$ matrices with determinant \$1\$.
- In theory the output must cover the whole \$SL_n(\mathbb R)\$ (that is, if the RNG you're using was perfect and we could actually represent real numbers).
- We don't require an *uniform* distribution.
- Instead of real numbers it is sufficient to work with floating point numbers.

Comment: I suspect the interesting solution you have in mind is to start with the identity and do random row operations. But maybe it's shorter to just generate a random matrix and divide the first row by its determinant, even if your language means you need to implement det yourself?

Comment: On second thought, random row operations is probably shorter to golf. And there's probably niftier ways to it like generating the LU decomposition, or taking the exponential of a trace-zero matrix. So this definitely seems like an interesting challenge to golf, at least for languages that don't make it too easy. A technical issue that might be worth addressing is whether it's OK to never be able to generate some probability-zero subset. For instance, what if the method only generates matrices with distinct eigenvalues? I think this should be allowed since floats can't reach everything either.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for you input! This task actually came up when I was trying to test a function I've written and I ended up using the random matirx/scale by determinant solution. I see your point about the zero-probability sets. The only problem I see is that it is hard to define it in a way that cannot be abused: As matrices with floats have only rational entries you could argue that we can only represent a zero-probability set in the first place. (If we use this exact wording.) So I'm not actually sure how to specify this.

Comment: I think it would be OK to say that in theory, the output must cover cover the whole space except for some probability-zero subset of it. I see what you're saying about floats being measure zero, but I think this wrinkle is already present and covered by you saying "in theory" and that floating points suffice for reals, so I don't see the change making it more abusable. I also realized that the code probably should be allowed to fail with theoretical probability zero, like if you go the determinant-scaling route, you could get det zero. Maybe defaults cover this already, I'm not sure.

Comment: As a side thought, it could be possible to avoid these annoying real-representation issues by changing the challenge to generating integer examples or ones over F_2, but I suspect this won't allow as wide a variety of solutions.

Comment: "We don't require an uniform distribution." -- would a Dirichlet distribution be allowed?

Comment: @xnor Even though \$\mathbb{F}_2\$ allows the possibility for bit-fiddling in solutions, possibly being interesting in their own rights.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Can you elaborate how you'd define a Dirichlet distribution over \$SL_n(\mathbb R)\$? I'm not familiar with this distribution and I don't quite see how we can apply it as the support seems to be defined as \$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n\$ with \$\sum_i x_i =1\$.

Comment: I though of something along the lines of \$P[X\neq\mathrm{id}]<\epsilon\$, where \$X\$ models the output and \$\epsilon\$ represents machine accuracy, however on second thought this case is covered by your theoretical surjectivity requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[Posted. I prefer to retain the content for potential issues.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193467/duck-duck-gone)

### Duck, duck, gone!

Here is the (quite childish) Five little ducks song(it is not long):

```
Five little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only four little ducks came back.

Four little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only three little ducks came back.

Three little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only two little ducks came back.

Two little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only one little duck came back.

One little duck went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but none of the little ducks came back.

Mother duck herself went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
and all of the little ducks came back.
```

Your task is not to output this song. You should take a verse and output the next verse (the next verse of the last verse is the first verse).

### Rules

- No standard loopholes, please.
- Input/output will be taken via our standard input/output methods.
- The *exact* verse must be outputted, and there should be no differences when compared to the song lyrics. The input will not be different when it is compared to the song lyrics too.

### Examples

```
Mother duck herself went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
and all of the little ducks came back.
```

Expected:

```
Five little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only four little ducks came back.
```

```
Three little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only two little ducks came back.
```

Expected:

```
Two little ducks went out one day,
over the hills and up away.
Mother Duck said, "Quack Quack Quack Quack",
but only one little duck came back.
```

### Sandbox

- Is it detailed enough?
- Is the input/output rules clear enough?
- Do I need any more information?

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: So a simple (no regex needed, case insensitive) string replacement `Five`→`Four`, `Four`→`Three`, `Three`→`Two`, `Two little ducks`→`One little duck`, `One little duck`→`Mother duck herself`, `four`→`three`, `three`→`two`, `two little ducks`→`one little duck`, `only one little duck`→`none of the little ducks`, `none`→`all of`?

Comment: Yes. (It seems quite repetitive, a better algorithm might be possible.) Do you think that outputting the whole lyrics is better?

Comment: No, it is no more interesting than 99 bottles etc.

Comment: You might replace the content with "posted" and a link now.

Comment: Your link is to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Polynomials Through Points

You will get a set of `n` Cartesian coordinates. You must output a polynomial going through all of the points.

### Input

- Points are 2-dimensional.
- You may assume that no two points share a x coordinate.
- You may take points as a tuple of pairs, or pair of equal length tuples.
- 1<`n`<1000

### Output

- For polynomial `y=x^3+3*x^2+1`, you may output as:

  - `y=x^3+3*x^2+1`
  - `x^3+3*x^2+1`
  - `y=x^3+3*x^2+0*x+1`
  - `x^3+3*x^2+0*x+1`
  - `y=x^3+3*x^2+x^0`
  - `x^3+3*x^2+x^0`
  - `y=x^3+3*x^2+0*x^1+x^0`
  - `x^3+3*x^2+0*x^1+x^0`
  - `y=1*x^3+3*x^2+1`
  - `1*x^3+3*x^2+1`
  - `y=1*x^3+3*x^2+0*x+1`
  - `1*x^3+3*x^2+0*x+1`
  - `y=1*x^3+3*x^2+1*x^0`
  - `1*x^3+3*x^2+1*x^0`
  - `y=1*x^3+3*x^2+0*x^1+1*x^0`
  - `1*x^3+3*x^2+0*x^1+1*x^0`
  - `[1,3,0,1]`
- You may output any polynomial satisfying the condition.

### Rules

- Stabdard loopholes are forbidden.
- Any method approved by Standard I/O is allowed.
- This is `code-golf`, so shortest code wins!

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest way to get an EOF Error

It's simple, simply write the shortest code to raise an EOF Error. An EOF Error happens when the language expects more code to be entered into the source code; however, the language encounters an EOF character. So here is a sample Python program to throw an EOF error.

```
id(
```

Python expects more code to be entered, but EOF is entered instead. Therefore it throws an "EOF Error" (technically a Syntax Error though, but the interpreter says `unexpected EOF while parsing`).

To simplify that, output text to STDERR containing the string `EOF`. Normally a language will exit after outputting to STDERR with an error, so if you are hard-coding the value out to STDERR, you should also exit the program with a 1 value.

### Input/Output

Your input will be none; however, you should output a message to STDERR that proves that the program generates an EOFError.

### Rules

- Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins.
- No standard loopholes please.
- Any method approved by Standard I/O is allowed.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[error-message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-message)

### Feedback

- Is this clear enough?
- I don't believe this is a duplicate (I found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188973/shortest-way-to-get-a-typeerror), but it's restricted to a single language), but does anyone recognise this?
- The tags as code-golf, error-message. Anything else?
- Any further feedback?
- Is it possible to have trivial answers on most languages for this challenge?

Comment: So just taking empty input would cause an EOF error? That'd lead to a whole bunch of trivial 1 byte answers in golfing languages.

Answer (score 1):

## A Musical Tuner

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

Oh no! My tuner's batteries ran out, I need to play in a concert in a few minutes, and I need to know if my instrument's in tune! I need this tuner quick, so it needs to be short.

## Background

In music, all notes are given a letter from `A-G/H`, an optional sharp/flat `♯/♭`, and a number specifying what octave it is in, starting from 0. This is called [scientific pitch notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation).

In [equal temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament), \$\sqrt 2 \approx 1.05946 \$ is an important ratio, as used in the formula $$ P_n = P_a (\sqrt2)^{n-a} $$ where

- \$ P_n \$ is the desired frequency, in hertz.
- \$ n \$ is the number of keys from the left on a piano the desired note is.
- \$ P_a \$ is the reference frequency, in hertz.
- \$ a \$ is the number of keys from the left on a piano the reference note is.

A piano begins at \$ A_0 \$ as the 1st key, and with reference frequency of \$ A_4 = P_a = 440 \$ Hz, at the 49th key.

The whole step, the tonal distance between two notes separated by one key, is divided into 100 cents. A half step is exactly 50 cents.

## The Challenge

Write a full program that, when given a decimal number in hertz, outputs the closest note in scientific pitch notation, and how far it is from that note in cents.

## Input

A positive number in hertz. This can be a string, number, list of whole number and decimal, etc. You can always assume this to be positive, and a number with maximum 3 decimal places.

The input is in the range \$ 27.5 \le P_n \le 4186 \$.

## Output

A note in scientific pitch notation, and how many cents it is from, in the form

`[Note letter][Sharp/Flat][Octave number][+/-][Cents]`

- If a note is determined to be close to a natural note, no sharps or flats should be output.
- Output either sharps or flats.
- Sharps can be either `♯/#` , and flats either `♭/b`.
- Octave number ranges from 0 to 8.

## Other Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Shortest code wins.

## Test Cases

```
Input --> Output
440 --> A4
261.626 --> C4
24.995 --> G♯0-8 (OR G#0-8)
1320.068‬ --> E6+1
3674.882‬ --> B♭7-13 (OR Bb7-13 OR A7+13)
```

Comment: The `+/- 1 cent` rule seems to be an unnecessary complication, I would suggest removing that.

Comment: The third example seems to be outside of the input range. I might be missing something obvious (I am almost entirely ignorant of music theory) but I don't think you explain how to get the note letter or the sharp/flat from the frequency. I think your question is unclear if you don't specify how that works in your challenge body. I assume what you intend for us to do is use the formula you provide to find \$ n \$ and then look up what key on a piano \$ n \$ refers to? In which case I think you should include the list of keys in order.

Answer (score 1):

### Subtract two numbers with Rule 110

**Background :**

It is known that Rule 110 is Turing complete, but in general, I have seen a lack of actual programs that utilize this property of Rule 110, so I propose that we do something about it ;)

**Some explanation**

Rule 110 is a one dimensional [cellular automaton](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CellularAutomaton.html), consisting of cells on/off, and the neighbors of those cells change the cell in the next iteration. 
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is a page detailing how rule 110 works, but here is also a basic table that summarizes the rule (the center number is the current cell's state, the two on the outside are its neighbors, the number to the right of the equals is the state for the next generation)

```
111 = 0
110 = 1
101 = 1
100 = 0
011 = 1
010 = 1
001 = 1
000 = 0
```

**The Challenge**

I want you to subtract two numbers, unsigned, eight bits long (No handling of negatives, input one will always be greater than or equal to input two)

Note : Index 0 is where the first 1 starts, which denotes your program, simply because the "tape" is infinite, and leading zeroes cannot be distinguished, so it must start at the first one

Input have to be inputted in unary, and must be inputted at a set interval from a specific point from the beginning of your program, and the inputs must not overlap. That may sound confusing, but here are some examples.

First, clarification on input. Input needs to be 8 bits long, and must be formatted to be so, if you had zero, it would be inputted as follows : 00000000, 2 would be 00000011, 7 would be 01111111 etc..., up to eight.

The first input is at intervals of 2 starting at index 1, the second input has an interval of 3 and starts at 25

```
1 _ 01 _ 01 _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _ 101 = 011 = 111 = 000 = 110 = 110 = 110 = 001 = 1010100101
```

The "_" is the first input, the "=" is the second input, they cannot overlap, and the interval represents the set distance that they must be seperated by. The bits themselves are inputed as ones, so if my first input was 00000111 and my second input 00111111 then my program would look like this

```
1 0 01 0 01 0 10 0 10 0 10 1 10 1 10 1 101 0 011 0 111 1 000 1 110 1 110 1 110 1 001 1 1010100101
```

The output is also defined in a similar fashion, from the start of the program (denoted by a 1) at specific intervals the bits represent the unary output

Example:

input one = 00011111, input two = 00000011

output = 00000111

**Score**

The number of bytes from the first one to the last one in the initial program.
Lowest score wins! Good luck!!!

I thought this was ready for the main, but it wasn't, so if ya'll have any problems, please let me know and I'll address them, as I will for the problems already proposed

Comment: I think this is missing a lot before it can be a proper challenge, so sorry if this comes off as harsh, and thanks for using the sandbox. Since this is about a CA I don't understand what you mean by "bits" and "bytes" in several places, do you not mean to refer to cells? The difference between unary and binary IO is so significant that you should just pick one, having bonuses is highly discouraged anyway as it leads to unpleasant patterns for answerers. Is the scoring based on the initial width of the region that contains live cells? Or something else?

Comment: If you mean that there are boundary cells (i.e. bits with only 1 neighbour instead of 2) you probably need to specify their rules as 110 usually has an infinite tape. You should also definitely include an explanation of 110 in your post. I think it is possible that if you allow the IO to be anywhere you may wind up with weird solutions. Certainly you can't allow that for unary IO since then they could require the inputs interleaved and the output would immediately be available. I think what you suggest is ok as long as input 1 is entirely more left than input 2 (but I'm not sure).

Comment: I think your specification of the input looks good! I have somewhat minimal experience actually working with cellular automata so you probably want to run it past some other people before trusting me ;) Aside from that, I think you should specify the output a bit more (I assume it should be read on a certain generation? Or do you require steady state after a certain generation?). Then I think if you move the summary of 110 to your post (basically just copy the table) you just have some formatting / grammar issues until you are ready to post.

Comment: I think the question looks pretty good, the only thing left I think is using "bits" for unary. I think it might be good to explain even just with an example that zero is exactly `00000000` and two is exactly `00000011` etc. For more expert CA help try the nineteenth byte chatroom, or try to hunt down some of the users who got tetris working in GoL :)

Comment: Random weird question idea: "Now that we've done it in Life, create a game of Tetris in rule 110".

Answer (score 1):

## Fewest number of button presses to set the cook time

A GolfCo™ microwave oven has a 12-button keypad like this:

```
[1]  [2]  [3]
[4]  [5]  [6]
[7]  [8]  [9]
     [0]  [+30]
   [START]
```

### How the microwave operates

The microwave reads and processes button presses as follows:

1. Buttons [0]-[9] add the corresponding digit to the right end of the cook time, up to 4 digits total. Once started, these buttons do not function.
2. The [+30] button adds 30 seconds to the cook time, and starts the cooking process (if not already started).
3. The [START] button starts the cooking process.

The microwave can be programmed with a cooking time ranging from 1 second to 99 minutes and 59 seconds.

Any one or two-digit cook time is interpreted as seconds only, ranging from 1 to 99 seconds.

Any three or four-digit cook time is interpreted as two digits of minutes and two digits of seconds. In this mode, the minutes portion of the cook time can range from 0 to 99 minutes, while the seconds can range from 0 to 59 seconds.

### The challenge

Given a time in minutes:seconds (eg. "4:45" for four minutes and 45 seconds), print the button sequence with the least number of button presses required to set the cook time and start the cooking process.

As this is code golf, the smallest program in bytes wins.

#### Input

Input will be given in the common MM:SS format, where "MM" specifies minutes and "SS" specifies seconds, separated by a colon.

Minutes can be zero padded to 2 digits or the leading zero omitted, at the golfer's discretion. Minutes can range from 00 to 99.

Seconds will always be 2 digits, ranging from 00 to 59.

The cook time will range from 00:01 to 99:59.

#### Output

The program will output the sequence of button presses needed to program the cook time and start the microwave.

Buttons [0] to [9] will be output as the corresponding digit "0"-"9".

The [+30] button will be output as "+".

The [START] button will be output as "S".

#### Test cases

```
Input                  Output
=======================================
04:45 (or 4:45)        4 4 5 S
00:08                  8 S
00:30                  +
00:35                  5 +
00:20 (or 0:20)        2 0 S
01:20 (or 1:20)        8 0 S
01:25 (or 1:25)        8 5 S     ("2 5 + +" and "1 2 5 S" are both too long)
01:30 (or 1:30)        + + +     ("9 0 S" is also correct)
01:35 (or 1:35)        5 + + +   ("1 3 5 S" is also correct)
01:39 (or 1:39)        9 + + +   ("1 3 9 S" is also correct)
01:40 (or 1:40)        1 4 0 S   ("1 0 + + +" is incorrect)
01:50 (or 1:50)        1 5 0 S   
02:00 (or 2:00)        2 0 0 S   ("+ + + +" is also correct)
02:30 (or 2:30)        2 3 0 S   ("+ + + + +" is incorrect)
03:00 (or 3:00)        3 0 0 S   
10:00                  1 0 0 0 S
99:59                  9 9 5 9 S
```

Comment: Can we wait between pressing buttons? I think I've seen a related challenge.

Comment: @someone, can you please explain how it would help? The only way I can see is if pressing buttons 0-9 is allowed after the oven is started, which I realize now I didn’t not state in the challenge. Is there some other use?

Comment: to wait for 300s, is it allowed to do +0? To wait 291s, can you press +, wait for 1 second and press 0?

Comment: The +30 button starts the oven, and after the oven is started, the 0-9 buttons do not function.

Comment: Some microwaves let you do more than 59 for the seconds.  E.g. if I type in 87, it will read it as 1:27.  60 reads as 1:00, 192 reads as 2:32.  This can allow you to enter certain times in fewer button presses.  Would be an interesting added challenge to support this feature.  Basically, if the last 2 digits are more than 59, subtract 60 and add 1 to the minutes.  (It would raise the maximum up to 100:39, if you were to type 9999...) ***Edit***: I see you did this in one example - that rule should be explicitly stated if you want to make sure it's enforced.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, that is part of the challenge. The Input section states that the cook time will always been given as MM:SS and the allowed ranges, and the Operation section states that 1 or 2 digit cook times are interpreted by the microwave as seconds, from 01 to 99 seconds. Please let me know how I could edit to make that more clear.

Comment: I guess just make sure to say that the seconds can be from 0-99, even if there are more than 2 digits, like my 192 example.  (Although 192 is the same number of buttons as 232.  Better example would be 960 which reads as 10:00 and takes 1 less button than 1000.)

Comment: I think this would be more interesting if the 1-6 buttons were "instant start" number of minutes buttons and the 0 button allowed entering typing mode.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

## Disconnect a social network

<sup>A version of this question was used in the [2019 International Mathematical Olympiad](https://www.imo-official.org/year_info.aspx?year=2019), which is now public. Modifications italicised.</sup>

> A social network has *n* users, some pairs of whom are friends. Whenever user A is friends with user B, user B is also friends with user A. Events of the following kind may happen repeatedly, one at a time:
>
> > Three users A, B, and C such that A is friends with both B and C, but B and C are
> >     not friends, change their friendship statuses such that B and C are now friends, but A is
> >     no longer friends with B, and no longer friends with C. All other friendship statuses are
> >     unchanged.
>
> *Given the initial graph of users, find whether sequence of such events so that at the end of the sequence* each user is friends with at most one other user *exists, and if so output that sequence*.

### Test cases

These cases have *n* followed by a list of friendships in the graph, and output as a list of triples of people in order A-B-C (and `0` if no sequence of triples exists - note that this is different from `[]` in this particular output scheme, here `[]` means that the graph already satisfies the condition that each user is friends with at most one other user).

```
3, [[1,2], [2,3]]
[[1,2,3]]

3, [[1,3], [2,3]]
[[2,3,1]]

3, []
[]

3, [[1,2]]
[]

3, [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
0

6, [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
[[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [1,4,5], [1,5,6]]

6, [[1,2], [1,6], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
0

7, [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [5,6]]
[[2,1,4], [1,3,2], [1,2,4]]

4, [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4], [3,4]]
0

6, [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [4,5], [4,6], [5,6]]
[[2,1,4], [3,1,5], [5,1,6], [2,4,6], [4,5,3]]

5, [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5]]
0
```

Input and output format are flexible as long as they conform to standard I/O requirements, and standard loopholes are forbidden. (In particular, for the impossible case, the output can be anything which is not an output from a possible graph, such as `[[0,0,0]]` or an additional 'success' boolean.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: I suspect more answers will pretty much brute force the problem, trying all possible sequences. Are you OK with that? I don't know if there's a nice algorithm for this and you're hoping people make something like it. If you do want to restrict it, you could limit the run-time on test case or impose an algorithmic complexity ceiling.

Comment: Outputting either a list or 0 is not possible in strongly-typed languages. I'd suggest allowing some alternatives like `[[-1, -1, -1]]` or `[[]]` or a pair of a Boolean representing success and the list.

Comment: @xnor
a) I don't know what the optimal algorithm is, so it'd be hard for me to set a limit (I heard that it could have potentially been a submission to the IOI but i don't know what form that would have taken) - do you have suggestions on how to make a reasonable restriction? 
b) I'm happy with any output format, as long as it distinguishes between the "already done" and "impossible" cases

Comment: @xnor Do you think that a polynomial runtime bound would be interesting? Alternatively, would this make a good [tag:fastest-code] question? If it becomes a [tag:fastest-code] question, would I have to offer to test solutions on my machine?

Comment: Do you know if there's a polynomial run-time algorithm? I think people usually test fastest code on their machines. Maybe you can test on [TIO](https://tio.run/#), but I think people said that might not be too consistent.

Comment: @xnor I believe I have a polynomial run-time algorithm - [tag:fastest-code] is looking like probably a better challenge at this stage anyway... Since I don't have any idea what the best time-complexity is, should I make some large test cases of varying sizes to compare programs with?

Answer (score 1):

## Measure the Discrepancy

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Given a finite sequence of real numbers \$ s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n\$ and an interval \$I=[a,b]\$ that contains the whole sequence, find its *discrepancy* \$D_n\$.

#### Definition*

Let \$I = [a,b]\$ be an interval that covers the whole sequence \$(s_i)_i\$, that means for all \$i\$ we have \$s_i \in I\$. The discrepancy \$D_n\$ is defined as

$$D_n = \sup_{[u,v] \subseteq I} \left| \frac1n N(u,v)  - \frac{v-u}{b-a} \right|$$

Here \$N(u,v) = \#\{i \mid 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n, s_i \in [u,v]\}\$ denotes the number of values of the sequence \$(s_i)_i\$ that are in the interval \$[u,v]\$.

<sup>* Technically the discrepancy \$D\$ is defined for infinite sequences as \$D = \lim_{n\to \infty} D_n\$. Intuitively speaking, the *discrepancy measures how uniformly distributed the sequence is in the given interval \$I\$. Sampling an uniform distribution on \$i\$ infinitely many times results in an discrepancy of \$D=0\$.</sup>

#### Examples

to be added...

Comment: I feel like `u - v` should be `v - u`?

Comment: @Kroppeb You're right, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: There is always the issue of taking real numbers as input, since there are more real numbers than binary strings.  How should this fact be handled?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic We usually take floats as representations of reals. But I think we could even restrict it to integers and it wouldn't change much.

Comment: I think that this challenge is more interesting if you need answers to be precisely correct.  Floating points open this up to brute force approaches which then boil down to just doing the operations.  Which I just don't think is as interesting.

Comment: Please include a plain English description of the challenge. Surely I can't be the only one here that can't read mathematical notation!

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for the feedback. I don't think I could remove *all* notation, but at the same time I have difficulties knowing where to start. Can you maybe point some notations out that you do or do not understand or think the average users might have trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

> It was found that this challenge is a duplicate. if you would like to see the challenge, please look in the revision history.

Comment: I just searched for the first two words: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/cambridge-transposition

Answer (score 1):

## Follow the Path

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195111/follow-the-path-but-is-it-valid).

Answer (score 1):

## Fermat's Last Theorem, mod n

It is a well known fact that for all integers \$p>2\$, there exist no integers \$x, y, z>0\$ such that \$x^p+y^p=z^p\$. However, this statement is not true in general if we consider the integers modulo \$n\$.

You will be given \$n\$ and \$p\$, which are two positive integers with \$n>1\$. Your task will be to write a function or program to compute all positive integers \$x, y, z<n\$ such that \$(x^p+y^p)\$ and \$z^p\$ give the same remainder when divided by \$n\$.

## Input

Any reasonable method of input is allowed. E.g. two separate user inputs, ordered pair, two function parameters, etc.

## Output

Any reasonable method of output is valid, it may be produced by a function or output to the screen. The order the triples are listed does not matter. Triples such as `(1, 2, 3)` and `(2, 1, 3)` are considered distinct, and all distinct triples should be listed exactly once. No invalid/trivial triples such as `(0, 0, 0)` should be output.

## Examples

```
n p -> Possible Output
----------------------------------------------------------------
2 3 -> []
3 3 -> [(1,1,2),(2,2,1)]
3 4 -> []
4 3 -> [(1,2,1),(1,3,2),(2,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(3,1,2),(3,2,3)]
```

## Scoring

Shortest code in bytes with no standard loopholes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Comment: I'd wager the average user of this site isn't particularly familiar with the mathematical notion of modulus, compared to the programming concept. I suspect some of them will find the last statement in the intro slightly confusing (my guess thinking that only the RHS is taken in modulus). Beyond clarifying that, I think you should specify in your test cases which parameter is which (i.e. `n p -> result` as the first line).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I have fixed those issues, is there anything else?

Comment: I don't see anything beyond adding some more test cases (particularly with larger `n`). Technically, this could be calculated for large `p` even if the intermediate results wouldn't work for a particular data type, but I assume you don't want to require that? Other than that it looks good to me, but of course I'm just one person, so I'd still wait a while.

Answer (score 1):

## **Sort and Table a Sentence by Word Lengths**

In as few bytes as possible, sort the input, *a delimited string OR list/vector/array of words containing printable ASCII except space* into a table (or something resembling a table). I tried to make the table rules as code friendly as possible to allow golfing and non-golfing languages alike to compete. Table rules are as follows:

- optional order, shortest to longest or vice versa, letter counts are required
- formatting is not the challenge, but to repeat the above rule, letter count is required. So as long as the output is some form of numerically labelled rows of words, a numbered list, or a list of lists, or similar output, then it is a satisfactory answer.
- including/excluding gaps (NA values, see below examples for both methods of output)
- Word case is untouched. How the word appears in input should be shown in output.

**Input 1:**

```
Code Golf and Coding Challenges Meta
```

**Output 1:**

```
 1. NA
 2. NA
 3. and
 4. Code Golf Meta
 5. NA
 6. Coding
 7. NA
 8. NA
 9. NA
 10. Challenges
```

**or**

```
3. and
4. Code Golf Meta
6. Coding
10. Challenges
```

**or**

```
[[3, ['and']], [4, ['Code', 'Golf', 'Meta']], [6, ['Coding']], [10, ['Challenges']]]
```

**Input 2:**

```
My very excellent mother just served us nine pizzas. #JusticeForPluto
```

**Output 2:**

```
1. NA
2. My us
3. NA
4. very just nine (alphabetized version: just nine very)
5. NA
6. mother served pizzas (mother pizzas served)
7. NA
8. NA
9. excellent
10. NA
11. NA
12. NA
13. NA
14. NA
15. NA
16. #JusticeForPluto
```

**or**

```
2. My us
4. very just nine
6. mother served pizzas
9. excellent
16. #JusticeForPluto
```

**or**

```
[[2, ['My', 'us']], [4, ['very', 'just', 'nine']], [6, ['mother', 'served', 'pizzas']], [9, ['excellent']], [16, ['#JusticeForPluto']]]
```

More examples can be provided if necessary but I think this should suffice for now.
Please give me pointers, this is my second attempt at a challenge. (the first failed dramatically)

Comment: Are the letter counts a required part of the output? I would suggest removing the requirement of filtering punctuation and just allow input as a delimited string or array of words.

Comment: @Shaggy That is a very good suggestion. I think that that is a fantastic idea. I'll make the edit.

Comment: @Shaggy I don't see why it would be difficult for letter counts to be required in the output. The idea is to place them in rows of a table that denote the word lengths within its row.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting they *shouldn't* be included, but, if they *must* be included, that you make that clearer in the spec.

Comment: What constitutes a "table?" Is the formatting you've used required, or is something like [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1cnJyMlRS895///aHXn/JRUdR0Fdff8nDQQnZiXAqKAwpl56WBWRmJOTmpeemoxiOebWpKoHgsA) alright? If it isn't, it seems like around half the code in several golfing languages will be devoted to formatting. Is that the intent?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you for the suggestion. I don't want formatting to be the focus of the challenge, but rather than just placing words in a list/array/vector with some form of label. Essentially a list of lists as you've done. I'll make the change

Comment: Thanks for the edits, though I don't think you need to include the program I wrote (it may even be more confusing since not many people read Pyth). I'd also recommend including something saying what class of characters the words will be drawn from, like "printable ASCII except space" or something.

Answer (score 1):

## Sand timer puzzler (code-golf)

I was googling for a sand timer and found this little item: [set of joined sand timers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M0GETKJ), for 3, 4, and 5 minutes each.

That of course reminded me of [multiple puzzles](http://www.mytechinterviews.com/9-minutes) about measuring X minutes using only M- and N-minute timers or whatever.

The mission then, if you choose to accept, is:

```
write a program that takes 3 integer inputs 0<A<B<C<100
and outputs list of all possible times that can be measured
using 3 joined sand timers A, B, and C up to 2 hrs
```

Test cases:

[in progress]

Comment: Isn't this basically any number that can be formed by some combination of multiples of `A`, `B` and `C`? Some test cases would be nice, and an objective winning criterion (such as [tag:code-golf]) is mandatory

Comment: I'm not clear what can be done with the timers. Can you flip any timer only when a timer runs out? Can you tell when two timers are the same level? Are the timers joined together like in the picture? If the answer turns out to be any multiple of the GCD of the numbers, I think that would make for a pretty boring challenge. Minor thing: I'd suggest writing "120 minutes" rather than 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

edit: check it out live here!

[Play Big 2 by yourself, as fast as you can](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196850/play-big-2-by-yourself-as-fast-as-you-can)

Comment: Seems a good first go. There is one major ambiguity I can find: You don't explain if aces are high or low. From your straight explanation, I guess they can be both, but you can't 'wrap' around. Please add an explanation about that.
Also, the straight flush, while a Poker hand, isn't required algorithmically: It's a subset of both straights and flushes, so any algorithm detecting them will also catch the straight flush.

Comment: Consider `3352 ['8C', '7C', '4C', '0C', 'AC']
3966 ['4H', '6D', '3S', '5H', '2S']
8063 ['AS', 'AH']
8191 ['8D']` for the first test

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/cgm-a18285-1 -- tio (may run more than \$1\$ min for \$hands\ge7\$)

Comment: @AlienAtSystem you're right - aces can be used as a high or a low, but they can't appear in the 'middle' of a straight, so to say. I'll update the straight description. Re: the straight flush - yeah I figured this too, mostly adding it for the sake of completion. I'll also make a note about that. Thanks for reading through it!

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin ack, you're right! I came up with the suiting on a whim and didn't really sit down to consider if it was possible to dump the hand faster. Oops. I meant to use the first test case as a general explanatory case, so I'll update my tests to reflect that. (Also, it seems like your tinyurl link is broken...)

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/cgm-a18285-2 -- I use [bfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) with early exit if goal reached, so it can't be done faster(in words of move numbers, not computation time). )

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Hmm, I still can't seem to use that link, but I appreciate your attempts nonetheless

Comment: One more )) http://tiny.cc/cgm_a18285_2

Comment: That link works like a charm, great work!

Answer (score 1):

## Guessing the subset.

### Preface

I've never done a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge before, so I'd appreciate some help to get this right. In particular, I'm not sure how much I should specify a (language-neutral) API. I'm also not sure how to implement time limits on computation time. (I want to be able to run a trial in seconds, not weeks.)

---

This challenge is based on Math Stack Exchange question ["Guessing a subset of {1,...,N}"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25270/121988).

In this challenge, the robber's job is to choose a subset \$R \subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}\$, *kind of*. Then the cop's job is to deduce the robber's subset by asking questions.

---

### Robber

When I was growing up, I would sometimes play [Twenty Questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions) with my brother. I would pick some sort of animal, and answer his questions about it. However, when he guessed the answer I had in mind, I would try to come up with another animal that satisfied all of the same answers to his questions—and if I could do it, I would tell him he was wrong.

The robber's job is similar to my strategy in Twenty Questions. The cop will ask the robber questions about the robber's chosen subset, but the robber can keep changing the subset as long as the answers are consistent. The robber's job is trying to answer the questions in such a way as to maximize the number of questions the cop needs to ask, always ensuring that the answers do not contradict each other.

### Cop

The cop's job is to successively pick subsets starting with \$C_1 \subseteq \{1, \dots, N\}\$ and ask the question, "Does \$C_1\ = R\$, and if not how many elements do \$C_1\$ and \$R\$ have in common?" (That is, \$|C_1 \cap R|\$.)

If \$C_k = R\$, then the cop has finished the interrogation, and her score is \$k\$. 
Otherwise, the cop then can use this information to choose a new set \$C_{k+1}\$, and ask the same question for \$C_{k+1}\$.

### Rules

Both the cop and robber will be given a number \$N\$, then the cop will go first outputting a subset \$C_1 \subseteq \{1,...,N\}\$. The robber will then take this as an input and output \$|C_1 \cap R|\$. The cop will take this number as an input and output \$C_2\$ and so on.

For a given interrogation both the cop's and robber's score is \$k\$ where \$C_k = R\$ is the last, correct guess. Naturally, the cop is trying to minimize her score while the robber is trying to maximize his.

Each cop will be tested against each robber (perhaps multiple times) with varying values of \$N \leq 1000\$. The score for the cop and robbers will be the sum of the scores over all interrogations.

Comment: I wish N was at most 24 so we can brute-force for 'giving the least information' answer as robber over 16M possible sets and then narrowing the set. Also consider [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195804/41420)

Answer (score 1):

## Count the length of head movement

[Moved here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196792/count-the-length-of-head-movement)

Answer (score 1):

## plan an efficient finnish bus stop on a sphere

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Apparently respecting personal space is very important at [finnish bus stops](https://twitter.com/vilsepi/status/795254546763313152?lang=it). Now given some "minimum-personal-space-angle" \$\vartheta\$, your job is designing a bus stop on a sphere for as many people as possible respecting the "minimum-personal-space-angle".

Let us rephrase this a little bit more clearly: Let \$S^2 = \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \Vert x \Vert_2 =1 \}\$ be the unit sphere in \$\mathbb R^3\$. Given the angle \$\vartheta \in (0,\pi)\$ you should find a set \$U \subset S^2\$ such that all pairs of vectors \$x,y \in U\$ (\$x \neq y\$) are at least an angle of \$\vartheta\$ apart, that is \$x \cdot y \leqslant \cos \vartheta\$.

And this set \$U\$ should be as large as possible - but this does not mean that your program needs to find the largest possible \$U\$ (this is a hard unsolved problem), but it should try to make it as large as possible as this will be part of the score.

Let us define \$a_\vartheta = \vert U \vert\$ as the number of vectors your program found for \$\vartheta\$.

The score \$s\$ of your submission will be

$$ s=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_{\vartheta_n} w_n$$

where \$\vartheta_n = 1/n\$, \$w_n = 1/n^2\$. And you can choose \$N \in \mathbb N\$ as large as you want.

Inspired by [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/e3go8b/question_maximum_number_of_vectors_in_rn_that_are/).

## META:

I think the choice of \$\vartheta_n\$ and \$w_n\$ needs some fine tuning to make the challenge interesting. My thoughts so far: The idea is that \$a_{\vartheta} \leqslant c \frac{1}{\vartheta^2}\$ since every vector on the sphere needs a circle of a radius that is at least \$\vartheta/2\$, so the area of such a circle is about \$\pi (\vartheta/2)^2\$ which means we can fit at most \$\frac{4\pi}{\pi (\vartheta/2)^2} = \frac{1}{\vartheta^2}\$ (just as a rough estimate).

So I think with current choice of \$\vartheta_n\$ and \$w_n\$ the score should be bounded. But I fear that with the current choice of these sequences the greatest score will be achieved by a relatively simple solution where someone just chooses \$N=1,2\$ or so.

Can we alleviate this by adding a factor of \$\log n\$ to \$w_n\$? Unfortunately I think this would incentivise using very large \$N\$.

---

**EDIT**: Instead of using \$\log n\$ I think using a *bounded* increasing sequence would work. E.g. \$(1-1/n)\$ so \$w_n = \frac{1}{n^2}(1- \frac{1}{n})\$.

---

If you have any thoughts or ideas, please share!

Comment: I didn't have time to actually think about this challenge, but my first reaction is that it seems weird to let the solver choose N. Might balancing the scoring be easier if you pick some value high enough to be interesting and specify it in the challenge?

Comment: @xnor thanks for the feedback! I thought maybe some answers would include very inefficient algorithms. While I cannot directly prevent those, I thought it would be a nice idea to try to discourage them via the scoring method. So ideally you'd get the best solution every time, and if not, get solutions that are as good as possible for the most possible `n`. I know it looks quite convoluted:)

Comment: This seems neat, but I did stumble at one point in understanding. You say \$ a_{\vartheta} \$ is what the program found, which led me to believe this value was going to be fixed in the scoring. I think if you change it to "finds" it will be pretty immediately clear that what I thought isn't correct. Also, assuming I'm reading correctly we never consider angles greater than 1 radian, which is a tad surprising following the definition (not really a problem, just something I noticed).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes this is correct. For \$\vartheta=\pi/2\$ the optimal \$a_\vartheta\$ is 6 (octahedron). For \$\vartheta \approx 0.9680399...\$ the optimal number is \$a_\vartheta=12\$ (icosahedron), so \$\vartheta=1\$ must be somewhere in between, and my thinking was that for angles this large, optimal solutions can easily be found. But it would easily be possible to define a totally different sequence for \$\vartheta_n\$ - if you have a suggestion let me know!

Answer (score 1):

## Roll for Initiative!

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

## Introduction

In tabletop games like Dungeons and Dragons, when you begin a battle, all involved parties *roll for initiative*. In DnD 5e, this is `1d20 + DEX + Other bonuses`, where `DEX` is the bonus given by your Dexterity stat. The characters that roll higher numbers go first. We'll use a similar, deterministic system in this challenge.

## The Challenge

Write a program or function that, when given a list of characters, will output a list of characters in order of initiative.

A character is defined as this:

```
character = {
    name: "name" // a string
    statblock: [SPD, DEX, WHT] // a list of numbers
                               // DEX = dexterity, SPD = speed, WHT = weight
}
```

The formula for initiative is the following:
$$\text{Initiative} = \left\lfloor{ \frac{\text{SPD}^2}{\sqrt{\lvert\text{DEX}\rvert}} }\right\rfloor - \text{WHT}$$

## Input

A list of characters, unsorted. This can be a JSON object, a list of lists, a list of dictionaries, a series of strings etc.

It is guaranteed that all names will be unique.

## Output

A list of characters, or character names, sorted by initiative order from highest to lowest, based on the above formula.

## Rules

- IO can be used with [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest program wins!

## Sample IO

```
Input --> Output
[[Name, SPD, DEX, WHT], ...]
    --> [[Name, SPD, DEX, WHT], ...] (or [Name, Name, ...])
---------
[[Alice,1,2,3],[Bob,10,5,0],[Charlie,3,2,1]]
    --> [Bob, Charlie, Alice]
// Alice = -3, Bob = 44, Charlie = 5

[[Z,1,1,1],[B,1,1,1],[XY,5,1,1]]
    --> [XY, Z, B]
// Retain the order of characters from the input if they have the same initiative.
// Z = 0, B = 0, XY = 24

[[Neg,-3,-3,-1],[SomeNeg,5,-2,-4],[NoNeg,4,6,8]]
    --> [SomeNeg, Neg, NoNeg]
// Negative values are valid.
// Neg = 6, SomeNeg = 13, NoNeg = -2

[[Flo,1.5,2.5,3.5],[MoreFlo,2,2.5,3.5]]
    --> [[MoreFlo,2,2.5,3.5], [Flo,1.5,2.5,3.5]]
// Floats are also valid.
// Flo = -2.5, MoreFlo = -1.5

[[Lonely,1,2,3]]
    --> [[Lonely,1,2,3]]
// Input with 1 item.

[]
    --> []
// Empty input leads to empty output.
```

Comment: You can use `\left` and `\right` in mathjax to make your brackets the right size. I also think that the output format is a little pointlessly strict - why not also allow just the list of names (same with requiring stable sorts)?

Answer (score 1):

## Name the hydrocarbon

A hydrocarbon is a chemical compound which consists of only hydrogen and carbon atoms. For this challenge, we will only consider the three simplest kinds of hydrocarbons: **alkanes**, **alkenes**, and **alkynes** with no branches.

An **alkane** with \$n\$ carbon atoms contains \$2n+2\$ hydrogen atoms. An **alkene** with \$n\$ carbon atoms contains \$2n\$ hydrogen atoms. An **alkyne** with \$n\$ carbon atoms contains \$2n-2\$ hydrogen atoms.

Each kind of hydrocarbon is named with a prefix indicating the number of carbon atoms it contains, followed by the suffix `ane`, `ene`, or `yne` if it is an alkane, alkene, or alkyne respectively. The numerical prefixes are as follows:

```
1  -> meth
2  -> eth
3  -> prop
4  -> but
5  -> pent
6  -> hex
7  -> hept
8  -> oct
9  -> non
10 -> dec
```

For example, we can see `propane` has 3 carbon and 8 hydrogen atoms, and `heptyne` has 7 carbon and 12 hydrogen atoms.

### Challenge

Your task is to write a function or program that receives two integers, representing a number of carbon and hydrogen atoms, and produces or outputs the name of the corresponding hydrocarbon. Capitalization does not matter, and leading/trailing whitespace is allowed.

The input and output can be in any convenient format. You may assume the input will correspond to a valid hydrocarbon, and there are at most 10 carbon atoms.

### Examples

```
Input -> Output
1 4   -> Methane
3 8   -> Propane
7 12  -> Heptyne
10 20 -> Decene
```

### Rules

- No standard loopholes.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

Answer (score 1):

## Numbers without 'E'

In this trial, I wish for us to think only of digits and digit compounds, from two to six trillion. If any in this group contains, in a plain Latin writing form, an indication of what our prompt prohibits, it is cast out of this group.

If a digit or digit compound contains 100, 1000, or similar, "1" is not a part of its plain Latin writing form. 1000 would simply boil down to "thousand", although 4000 is "four thousand".

### What you must do:

**Taking an input of N, in which N is not as high as 1000, nor as low as 0, (0 < N < 1000), and in which N is an ordinal, output what N points to in an array that follows our titular prompt.**

Additionally, your solutions may contain only a solitary count of this cast out latin symbol (including diacritical marks and such, although this should not dismay you too much).

Your aim is to do this with a minimum bit count in your program.

This following portion is for clarification on what I am in pursuit of:

    `1 -> 2 (two)
    3 -> 6 (six)
    5 -> 32 (thirty two)
    22 -> 1004 (thousand four)
    100 -> 30 000 (thirty thousand)`

### Meta:

As you may have noticed, this is a little hard to read. I tried to spice it up by excluding any instance of the letter 'e' from the text description.

- Should the challenge be changed to "evaluate if a number contains 'E'"? This is an alternative idea Id considered but Im not sure if it would make a better challenge
- Does eliminating all instances of 'e' from the description make this challenge unreadable?
- Does the additional challenge of only having 1 'e' in the solution add too much to the challenge?
- Are the bounds too restrictive/not restrictive enough?

Comment: Hi there! These are called ["Eban" numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_number), and essentially has [already been asked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37707/42963); the difference being you're asking for the *nth* number, while the linked question is asking for the *first n*.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I see, I had searched for similar questions but couldnt find anything. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

## What's that frequency?

*This is my first code-golf challenge, so apologies if it is a little  unclear/already has been done. I gave the past challenges a good look over, but I may have missed something.*

Create a function or a full program which accepts a frequency value, and then outputs the closest musical note, and the octave, this frequency corresponds to.

This function/program should support eight full octaves worth of notes, starting from C0 up to and including B8.

**Test cases:**

```
440.00 -> A4
466.16 -> A#4
466.20 -> A#4
261.63 -> C4
16.35 -> C0
0.00 -> C0
7902.13 -> B8
10000.00 -> B8
```

A full list of frequencies and notes they correspond to can be found here: https://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html

This is a code golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox! :) I found the [inverse challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69729/31625). I feel as though I've reviewed this version as well, but perhaps it never left the sandbox. In any case, you should include a method by which to classify the frequencies, and what precisely you mean by closeness in the body of your challenge. External links are nice but not enough!

Comment: Great idea! Just make sure to flesh out the rules: perhaps specify that `A=440Hz` and that each note is `2 ^ (1/12)` times the note below it (if I'm remembering my music theory correctly).

Comment: You may also want to consider adding some tags: [tag:music], [tag:code-golf]

Answer (score 1):

Challenge posted to Main [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196872/smallest-fibonacci-multiples)

Comment: I'd say this is very close to being a dupe of the Fibonacci challenge. Often one could pretty directly replace the (inc/dec)rement with a divisibility check. The specific nature of the Fibonacci challenge allows a lot of tricks that wouldn't work as well here, though.

Comment: Could you link to that challenge?

Comment: [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/31625) you go.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is there a way to modify this to invalidate more answers from that question? Maybe a new winning criterion?

Comment: You could try something like scoring each submission by the sum of each byte's smallest Fibonacci multiple? That's kind of a lazy fix (and you need to deal with null bytes, lenguage, etc.) but it could work. You can try asking in chat for more ideas, and of course if I think of anything I'll let you know :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How do you like the update?

Comment: I don't think your precise method of scoring is ideal, it seems like it could be abused to get a score of zero too easily. I recommend scoring actual bytes, not the unicode characters they turn into.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hmm, sorry for bugging you, but how would you suggest doing that? I'm not sure I see the picture.

Comment: I guesss something like Lenguage could come in and have a program full of spaces, henceforth getting a score of 0.

Comment: @Jono2906 I don't know how to modify this to make this work, frankly.

Comment: No worries, and I recommend not worrying too much about Lenguage and the like, they are often kind of impossible to fix. What I mean is, the characters used in code are ambiguous and not particularly meaningful. Instead, score based on the bytes of the program, which are clear and fixed. Then keep the part with the fib multiples, but add one to the bytes beforehand to avoid zero.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Makes sense! I'm pretty happy now with where this challenge is at.

Answer (score 1):

## Union of Two Polygons

Given two intersecting polygons as input, output a third polygon that is the union of the two input polygons, that is to say, the perimeter that encloses all points present in at least one of the two input polygons.

[image: Example polygon unions]

## Example inputs/outputs

#### 2 Squares

```
  [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)]
| [(1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1)]
==> [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)]
```

... more to come

## Notes and Rules

- Input will be two lists of at least 3 2d points each, taken in any convenient format.
- Output should be a list of 2d points, in any convenient format.
- It does not matter which point you list first.
- It does not matter whether you output in clockwise or counterclockwise order.
- Polygons may be concave
- You may assume that both polygons are not self-intersecting
- You may assume that the polygons overlap in at least two places exclusively via edge-edge crossings rather than vertex-edge intersections, vertex-vertex intersections, or flush edge-edge overlaps.
- You may assume that the polygons do not overlap in such a way that the union would have at least one hole in it.
- You must be accurate to at least 0.01 for all polygons between -100 and 100 units along each axis.
- Standard rules apply. Shortest code wins.

[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Answer (score 1):

## Sort By the New Alphabet

The order of the alphabet is really quite arbitrary. I propose a new ordering of the alphabet, ordered so that adjacent letters (in capital form) are similar in shape. Here is the order:

`JUOQGCDPRBEFTILVYXKHAMWNZS`

Of course, this makes a lot of previously written code redundant. To fix this problem we will start re-implementing that code, in its updated form.

Your task is to create a program or function that takes a string or list of characters as input, and outputs that string/list sorted according to this new ordering.

You can assume that all input will contain only uppercase alphabetic characters.

---

I know it's similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38532/sort-by-custom-alphabet) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165484/sort-a-string-by-a-given-ordering), but this challenge has a fixed ordering, so I hope this allows for some more ingenuity as well as the requirement to store the ordering efficiently.

Comment: Is uppercase mandatory, or are we allowed to take both input and store the compressed alphabet as lowercase?

Comment: You can store the alphabet however you want. You can accept input as upper or lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

## Expand a road network

*[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)*

---

You've been employed as a city planner <sub>[(obligatory seinfeld clip)](https://youtu.be/3DayjracBf8)</sub> and you have been tasked with expanding the road system of Codegolfville. Here's a diagram of what Codegolfville could look like:

```
        | |
        | |
--------+ +-------
--------+ +-------
        | |
        | +-------
        | +-------
        | |
        | |
```

Your job is to expand the existing infrastructure \$n\$ blocks in a specific direction.

## The Challenge

1. Take two inputs - a direction to expand in, and the number of blocks to expand - through any reasonable input format.
2. Expand the existing roadways in the ASCII map, in the direction specified.

   a. You must take into account the existing roadways - you can only expand on roads that are already there, and if there are no roads to expand, you won't expand anything.

   b. Your program must work for any example map, not just the one provided above.
3. Show the output on STDOUT, if your language supports it.

## Test Cases

*will be done soon*

## Other Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest score in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden. Have fun!

Comment: Are blocks a fixed dimension or is it based on the size of the input? Does it expand in only one direction or can it be multiple? Finally, what does expansion mean? Are we replicating the block n times? Merely extending the roads on the expanding edge (i.e. appending n*width `-` or `|`s)?

Answer (score 1):

### Make an "implicit" parser [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

In this task, given an infix expression, fill in all of the implicit inputs *and* evaluate this expression with the other given input. (You only need to deal with (`+`, `-`, and `()`.)

Expressions are only allowed to be dyadic and not monadic. If an operator is monadic, prepend an input.

### What do I do?

The rule is simple: if something is preceded with a nilad or a parenthesized expression, it is a dyad.

`+` is a dyad here:

```
2 + 1
(5 + 2)
3 + ((2) + 4)
```

Otherwise, the operator is a monad.

`+` is a monad here:

```
 +(2 - 2)
(+ 2)
```

If you find a monad in your code, immediately prepend it with the `a` character.

```
a +(2 - 2)
(a+ 2)
```

That's about it.

### Examples

The input expression is guaranteed to not produce errors, such as the format `2-` which is impossible to prepend an input.

```
"+++a",2 -> a+a+a+a = 2+2+2+2 = 8
"(+1)+(-1)",5 -> (a+1)+(a-1) = (5+1)+(5-1) = 10
"+(2-a)", 3 -> a+(2-a) = 3+(2-3) = 2
"(5+2)+2+1", 7 -> (5+2)+2+1 = 10
"--2", 2 -> a-a-2 = 0-2 = -2
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.

Comment: I've been thinking of making a challenge to parse a simple subset of APL e.g. numbers and `+` and `-` and `/`, but what does your challenge have to do with APL? APL *doesn't* have implicit arguments for nilads, and `a+(2-)` is a syntax error in most dialects.

Comment: @Adám (You said *nilad*, I assume you meant *monad*.) 1. I assume scanning for nilads was how APL was parsed. Correct me if I am wrong. 2. Although APL doesn't provide arguments, the only less trivial way I can think of compared to outputting how many arguments an operator has is to provide the arguments. Do you have a better way to do this? 3. To simplify the challenge, preventing syntax errors is unneccecary.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the "nilad" instead of "monad". 1. That's wouldn't work. 2. How about simply evaluating a given expression consisting of `[-+/ 0-9]? That's easy to verify against a real interpreter. 3. Just guarantee that the input expression has no errors.

Comment: What is the correct answer for `"--2",2`?

Answer (score 1):

## Blackjack

This is kept fairly simple, compared to a real Blackjack-Game:

Write a program that creates a blackjack game, where the input "h" means "hit" and "s" means "stand". Everything else outputs nothing, it just waits for the right input.

```
Rules:
- You can draw as many cards as you want, also to make it easier, there is no card limit.
  This means you could draw more than 4 Asses.
- The cards you can get are
  standard-cards (2-10, J, Q, K, A) where the Values are the default ones:

2-9 = 2-9,
10, J, Q, K = 10

- A is a special card. So to make it easy, the default value is 11.
  If a player gets over 21, the value gets reduced to 1.
  In the case that a player has two or more A-Cards, all but one A
  reduces to 1, giving a total value of 14 for 4 Asses. (11+1+1+1)

- The dealer needs to get in between 18-21. If the bank has reached a value in 
this radius,
it can't draw another card (For example: Bank reached 18.
                          It can't get another card to get closer to 21)

- The game runs forever
- hit means „draw another card“, stand means „stop with cards and wait for 
the dealer to reach his limit“

Procedure:

- The player gets 2 cards at the beginning, shown by "Player:" in the console 
  (Example: Player gets 2 and 5 at the beginning. 
  Console output: "Player: 2, 5").

- The cards can be shown in the console by their values
  (For example: 2, 10, 1 | No need for: 2, K, A), but you can also use 
  the card-names instead. Your choice. But you need to show the maximum
  value you have
  (for example:
  first draw console output "Player: 2, 4, 5 = 11",
  second draw console output "Player: 2, 4, 5, 7 = 18")

- The input by the player is "h" for "hit" and "s" for "stand". Also allowed 
  is 1 and 0

- In the console, the player is displayed by "Player:"
- In the console, the dealer is displayed by "Dealer:"

- After the player got two cards, the dealer gets one card.
  Then the player can hit or stand.
  After every card drawn from the player,
  the dealer gets another card until he reaches his limit. (18-21)

  If the dealer reaches 21 before the player does, the dealer wins.
  If the Player reaches 21 first, the player wins.
  If the dealer reached his limit, and the player stands on the same value, it's a draw.
  If the dealer is over 21 first, the player wins.
  If the player is over 21 first, the dealer wins.

- At the end you get the output "Win", "Lose", "Draw",
  or "Blackjack", depending on the game
```

This game is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, even the smallest result won'tbe under 150 bytes at least

Comment: @Noodle9 
1. If you want to write 'h' and mistype, then you basically ruined your win
2. Blackjack rules:
win = more points than dealer or Blackjack |
lose = less points than Dealer |
draw = same points as dealer |
Blackjack = 21 points straight |
3. As it's the easy version there is only one hand, will add that

Comment: Do you know blackjack? You draw cards and try to get as close to 21 as possible. If you get 21 you already have won the game. if you get 20 you could still draw a card, maybe it's an Ass. But you still need to get higher points than the dealer, but not more than 21

Comment: if you play with 52 cards you could draw up to 7 cards (4*Ass+ 3*2 = 20)

Comment: Yes I've played the game T_T But questions/challenges need to be self-contained with a full explanation for anyone who's doesn't know the game. Also you should edit your sandbox to include the things  above.

Comment: `If a player gets over 21, the value gets reduced to 1.` this contradicts the bit below of `all but one A reduces to 1, giving a total value of 14 for 4 Asses. (11+1+1+1)`

Comment: @Corsaka It doesn't. First ace you have 11, second ace makes that 22 so it gets reduced to 12, third ace makes that 23 so it gets reduced to 13, forth ace makes that 24 so it gets reduced to 14.

Comment: Ah, I misread that. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

## Asyncronous Breakfast

I haven't seen any asyncronous challenges here, even tho it's an important part of coding, so here's my idea, based on an example (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that explains asyncronous coding:

```
You are making breakfast. The things you want to serve are:
Cooked eggs, Bacon, Coffee, Orange Juice and Toast.

You start boiling the eggs, cooking the bacon, making coffee, and toasting toast. 
When everything is finished, you're serving the orange juice.

After every finished food, the console outputs "[Food] is ready."
```

Comment: I think you should generally only specify things about the input and the output, and not the program's internal behaviour ("do addition without the + operator"-like questions are now discredited). Can you define a required output in a way that the only way to produce it is for the program to run asynchronously?

Comment: How about checking the [tag:multi-threading] tag?

Answer (score 1):

## Decorate the Christmas Tree

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

### Intro

It's a week before Christmas and the your family just bought a Christmas tree. Your little sister has a box of ornaments which she wants you to decorate the tree with.

### Challenge

Write a function or program to randomly decorate the tree with all the ornaments from the box. All possible arrangements of ornaments on the tree must have a non-zero probability of occurrence.

### Input

1. height of the tree `n`
2. 'box' of ornaments (a string of printable ascii characters where each character represents an ornament) in which order doesn't matter. Also, you can assume that `'#'` will not show up as an ornament since it is used to draw bare branches.

Given the number of branches on a tree of size `n` is `(n-1)^2` you can assume that **the number of ornaments in the box will be less than or equal to the number of branches on the tree.**

Example of a box of ornaments: `o = '**@@***@@$$**OOOO....'`. Since this string is 21 characters long it can only be valid input for `n > 5`.

### Output

Print out the tree with its decorations

The tree is the following structure of ascii characters where `n` specifies the height of the tree:

```
//Tree where n=9                         //Tree where n=6
        #                                        #
       ###                                      ###
      #####                                    #####
     #######                                  #######
    #########                                #########
   ###########                                  |||
  #############
 ###############
       |||
```

Bare branches will always be represented with `'#'` and the bottom trunk is always `|||` while centered with center character of each row.

Examples of output with ornaments:

```
//n=9, o='X@@X%%%**&&'                   //n=6, o='OO*X*X'
        #                                        O
       ##%                                      O##
      #X###                                    #X#*#
     ###@##%                                  *######
    #&#######                                #####X###
   #@######X##                                  |||
  #####%##*####
 ##*######&#####
       |||
```

### Rules

- IO can be used with any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest program wins!

## Meta

- Is this too close to a duplicate?
- Are there any improvements or clarifications required?

Comment: By random, do you mean that every possible distribution of decorations should be equally likely? Or just that the distribution changes with each run?

Comment: What does the tree look like if `n` is even? That is, how does the trunk center?

Comment: Every level of the tree will have an odd number of characters, no matter what the value of n is, so the trunk should remain centered with the top level of the tree.

Comment: What can you put in the box of ornaments? Printable ascii characters? Unicode? Also, what if there's more ornaments than there is area of tree to put them on?

Comment: To add to frank's comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/36398

Comment: Regarding "a string of printable ascii and/or unicode characters"  You should know that handling unicode (millions of possible characters, from Urdu اُردُو‎ to cuneiform ) is a lot harder in many golfing languages than printable ascii (which is mostly just the Latin alphabet and some punctuation marks) - to the point where using the tag [tag:unicode] is advisable if you want the solution to handle unicode characters. If you want the possibility to handle every conceivable tree decoration, you should be more explicit about it than use an and/or construction.

Comment: Fair enough. Sticking to printable ascii should be fine then.

Comment: This feels _very_ familiar; I think we may have had it before but, maybe, without the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer `a` and any positive odd integer `n` the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) is defined as follows:
$$
\left(\frac{a}{n}\right) = 
\left(\frac{a}{p_1}\right)^{\alpha_1}
\left(\frac{a}{p_2}\right)^{\alpha_2}
\cdots
\left(\frac{a}{p_k}\right)^{\alpha_k}
$$
where
$$n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots{p_k^{\alpha_k}}$$
is the prime factorization of `n`.
The Legendere symbol is defined for all integers `a` and odd primes `p` as
$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = 
\begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$},\\
      1 & \text{if $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and for some integer $x$: $a \equiv x^2 \pmod{p}$},\\
      -1 & \text{if $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and there is no such $x$}.
    \end{cases}
$$

Your task is to write a function that will take two parameters: `a` and `v`, where `a` is a positive integer, and `v` is a list of `n` values. The function should return the index of the first value in `v` for which the Jacobi symbol is `-1`.
For this challenge, you may assume that all values in the `v` array are odd primes, and are greater than or equal to `a`. The length of `v` will be between 4 and 100 values. If no value in `v` produces a `-1` result for the Jacobi symbol, simply return the length of `v`.

Because each invocation of the function will execute very quickly, your function will be tested against a wide variety of inputs and the execution time will be summed. This process will be repeated 50 times and the best execution time will serve as your score. My machine is a 2018 Macbook Pro, with the following specs:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64 TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C
machdep.cpu.leaf7_features: SMEP ERMS RDWRFSGS TSC_THREAD_OFFSET BMI1 HLE AVX2 BMI2 INVPCID RTM SMAP RDSEED ADX IPT SGX FPU_CSDS MPX CLFSOPT
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536MB
RAM: 32GB 2400MHz DDR4
```

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Answer (score 1):

### Even-Odd chunks

(Inspired by the Keg utility of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197210/even-and-odd-numbers) challenge)

Given an input string, e.g. `s c 1= e(a"E")`, split the input into even-odd chunks.

### Example

This input string, when mapped to its code points, yields the list `[115, 32, 99, 32, 49, 61, 32, 101, 40, 97, 34, 69, 34, 41]`. When applied modulo-2 for every item, this returns `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

In this list let's find the longest possible chunk that is consistent with even and odd code points:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

For the first chunk, this yields `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` because this is the longest chunk that follows the pattern

```
Odd Even Odd Even Odd Even ...
```

or

```
Even Odd Even Odd Even Odd ...
```

. Adding another codepoint into `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]` breaks the pattern, therefore it is the longest possible even-odd chunk that starts from the beginning of the string.

Using this method, we should split the input into chunks so that this rule applies. Therefore the input becomes (the `;` here is simply a separator; this can be any separator that is not an empty string):

```
s c 1;= e(a"E")
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins. Let it be known that flags don't count towards being in the pattern. They also don't count towards byte count in this challenge.

Comment: Right now, the output specified in the introduction (Longest even-odd chunk) doesn't agree with the example, where you have instead the string split into even-odd chunks. Both would work as challenge, but you have to choose which.

Comment: I chose the latter because it is easier to specify.

Answer (score 1):

## Convert Character Substrings to Numeric

I often have to take character data and categorize it numerically. A common thing I do is to take character type variables and convert them to numeric type characters, keeping same categories according to the level of work I'm doing. (The longer the substring, the more in depth, shorter substrings for broad level). Enough backstory...

The challenge: **In as few bytes as possible,** convert the input part A, *a vector/list of unique strings*, into the output, a *vector/list of numbers*, keeping unique categories within the length of substrings the same length, which is input part B.

Input:

1. w, Vector/list of unique strings of equal character length. `n <= 10`

   - These strings may be any combination of uppercase letters and numbers. Sorry if it seems my examples follow a pattern, I just created them after a similar pattern I see in the data I work with.
2. s, where `1 <= s <= n`

Output: May take input and output in the same order, or you can convert alphabetically, but output in the same order. See example 2. (I've included comments in my output to clarify, this is not required)

**Example Input 1:**

```
#Already alphabetized, but this input is not always guaranteed

s = 3, w = 
[ABC01, 
 ABC11,
 ABC21,
 ABD01,
 ABE01,
 ABE02,
 ACA10,
 ACA11,
 ACB20,
 ACB21]
```

**Example Output 1:**

```
[1, #ABC
 1, 
 1, 
 2, #ABD
 3, #ABE
 3, 
 4, #ACA
 4, 
 5, #ACB
 5]
```

**Example Input 2:**
s = 4, w =

```
[X1Z123,
 X1Z134,
 X1Y123,
 X1Y134,
 X1Y145,
 X1Y156,
 X1X123,
 X1X124,
 X1X234,
 X2Z123,
 X2Z134,
 X2Z222,
 X2Z223,
 X2Z224]
```

**Example 2 Output:**

```
#Categorize by order
[1, #X1Z1
 1,
 2, #X1Y1
 2,
 2,
 2,
 3, #X1X1
 3,
 4, #X1X2
 5, #X2Z1
 5,
 6, #X2Z2
 6,
 6] 

OR if conversion follows alphabetical formatting,

#Categorize alphabetically, but output in same order as input.
[6, #X1Z1
 6,
 5, #X1Y1
 5,
 5,
 5,
 3, #X1X1
 3,
 4, #X1X2
 1, #X2Z1
 1,
 2, #X2Z2
 2,
 2]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused; the input matches the regex `[A-Z]+[0-9]+` and the task is to replace the inputs with unique integer identifiers based on the first `s` letters? Something like `as.integer(as.factor(substring(w,1,s)))`? I think it's a good challenge but needs a little more clarification.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I didn't specify how the input will appear. The input is not supposed to follow any specific regex pattern, but some inputs will be similar enough. It could be all uppercase letters or all numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### Partial tq interpreter [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

In this task you are expected to provide a **list** output given an input [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq) program. The tq programs will not contain whitespace inside them. (I find tq extremely difficult to implement within a short time, therefore I consider it to be a nice challenge.)

### What is tq, in the first place?

tq is a lazy-evaluated language that is designed with the idea that array items should be accessable during the definition of them. In tq, there is no explicit separator of an array, only special arrangements of monadic/dyadic functions and nilads.

The following program is a program printing `[123]` (Pretend that tq doesn't support strings because we aren't dealing with them in this case):

```
123
```

This defines a list with the first item being the number 123, after which all items in the list will be outputted inside a list.

In tq, numbers are supported to allow multiple-digits. So this defines a list with 2 items:

```
12+12,5
```

In this test case, you are expected to output the list `[24,5]`. Let's explain it step by step.

```
12+12   # This evaluates 12 + 12 in the current item in the list, returning 24
     ,  # A separator. This separates two items when they could be potentially
        # ambiguous when they are applied without a separator.
      5 # This evaluates 5 in the current item in the list, returning 5
        # The comma is simply a no-op that doesn't require parsing.
```

So you think that tq is not hard at all to implement? Well, remember that tq also has a special feature of accessing the items in an array before the array is defined!

```
555th123
```

We introduce two new atoms:

- `t` (**t**ail) means access the last item in the list
- `h` (**h**ead) means access the first item in the list

Therefore our list is going to yield:

```
[555,123,555,123]
```

Now take a look at this program:

```
555ps123
```

We introduce 2 more atoms:

- `p` Yield the next item *before* (**p**revious) the current position
- `s` Yield the next item *after* (**s**ucceeding)the current position

This yields the list:

```
[555,555,123,123]
```

### A quick reference of the tq language

Just assume that you only have two operands for the operators.

- `[0-9]` starts a number. Numbers will *only* be positive integers, i.e. no decimals and negative numbers.
- `,` This is a separator of different items when it is given that two consecutive indexes will be ambiguous with each other without a separator. In tq all of the remaining characters can act as a separator, but in this case it is a good idea to implement only `,` for the ease of your implementation.
- `+` and `*` These are arithmetic operators. Usually in tq, they may be applied multiple times, e.g. `1+2+3`, but in your implementation, input will be provided so that this will not happen and only `1+2` will happen (there will not be applications multiple times).
- `t` return the last item in the list. If the code is `t1,2,3` it shall return `[3,1,2,3]`.
- `h` return the first item in the list. If the code is `1,2,3h` it shall return `[1,2,3,1]`.
- `p` returns the item before the current item. If the code is `0,1,p,3,4` the code shall return `[0,1,1,3,4]`.
- `s` returns the item after the current item. If the code is `0,1,s,3,4` the code shall return `[0,1,3,3,4]`.

### More test cases

- `4p*p` will yield `[4,16]`
- `1p+s2` will yield `[1,3,2]`
- `1,2,3h+t4,5,6` will yield `[1,2,3,7,4,5,6]`
- `3ppss6` will yield `[3,3,3,6,6,6]`
- You also have to implement multiple hops. E.g. `1th` should yield `[1,1,1]`
- If you know that something is going to form a loop, e.g. `1sp2`, the cells that form the loop should be removed. Therefore the previous example will yield `[1,2]`.
- Out of bounds indexing will yield the closest index of the indexed item **that is a number**. E.g. `1,2s` should yield `[1,2,2]`

Answer (score 1):

## Decimal to String with Mandatory Length

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[floating-point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point)[conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion)

### Introduction:

Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59679852/1682559), which asks for the most accurate precision of decimal values using either rounding or scientific notation as string, with at most 15 characters long. This would include the `-`, `.`, and `E` in the output-string.

### Challenge:

Inputs:

- A decimal value \$s\$
- An integer output-length \$n\$

Output:

- A string of the most accurate representation of the given decimal value, with a length exactly equal to the output-length \$n\$. NOTE: the linked SO question ask for at most 15 characters long, but this challenge asks for *exactly* \$n\$ characters long instead.

### Challenge rules:

- The output-length input is guaranteed to be \$n\geq7\$
- The decimal input is guaranteed to be valid and non-empty
- You are allowed to take the input-decimal \$s\$ as string
- The input-decimal is guaranteed to only contain the characters `0123456789-.`, and will not start with an `.` (but `0.` instead), nor start with unnecessary leading `0`s like `001.23` instead of `1.23` (except for `0.`).
- The output-string is guaranteed to only contain the characters `0123456789-.E` (or `e` instead of `E` if you choose so). The input-format restrictions mentioned one bullet-point above, do NOT apply for the output-format however!
- If the length of the integer part of a number (including `-` for negative values) is larger than the given output-length: use a scientific notation (with either `e` or `E`) and rounded precision. I.e. with inputs `s = "-987654321987654321.987654321"; n = 15`, the output is supposed to be one of these: `["-987654321.99E9", "-9876543219.9E8", "-98765432199.E7"]`
- It is allowed to add leading `0`s to get to length \$n\$ without changing its decimal (base-10) value. I.e. with inputs `s = "-123.00"; n = 15`, the output `"-00000000000123"` would be valid.
- It is allowed to add trailing `0`s to the decimal parts to get to length \$n\$ without changing its decimal (base-10) value. I.e. with inputs `s = "-1.23"; n = 15`, the output `"-1.230000000000"` or `"-1.2300000000E0"` are both valid. (With inputs `s = "-0.123456789123456789"; n = 15`, the only possible output is `"-.1234567891235"`.)
- Please specify which rounding type your language is using! (E.g. HALF_UP, HALF_DOWN, HALF_EVEN, BANKERS, etc.) My test cases where this is relevant use HALF_UP.
- If multiple outputs are possible, just output one, multiple, or all of them.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

All these test cases will use the output-length as `15` (and rounding mode `HALF_UP`):

```java
Input:                           Possible Outputs:
"987654321987654321.987654321"   "987654321.988E9","9876543219.88E8","98765432198.8E7","987654321988.E6"
"-987654321987654321.987654321"  "-987654321.99E9","-9876543219.9E8","-98765432199.E7"
"1234567891234567.123456789"     "1234567.89123E9","12345678.9123E8","123456789.123E7","1234567891.23E6","12345678912.3E5","123456789123.E4"
"-1234567891234567.123456789"    "-1234567.8912E9","-12345678.912E8","-123456789.12E7","-1234567891.2E6","-12345678912.E5"
"0.123456789123456789"           ".12345678912346"
"-0.123456789123456789"          "-.1234567891235"
"5.5555555555555555555555555"    "5.5555555555556"
"-5.5555555555555555555555555"   "-5.555555555556"
"123456789123456"                "123456789123456"
"-123456789123456"               "-123456.78912E9","-1234567.8912E8","-12345678.912E7","-123456789.12E6","-1234567891.2E5","-12345678912.E4"
"123.00"                         "123.00000000000","0123.0000000000","00123.000000000","000123.00000000","0000123.0000000","00000123.000000","000000123.00000","0000000123.0000","00000000123.000","000000000123.00","0000000000123.0","00000000000123.","000000000000123","123.000000000E0","0123.00000000E0","00123.0000000E0","000123.000000E0","0000123.00000E0","00000123.0000E0","000000123.000E0","0000000123.00E0","00000000123.0E0","000000000123.E0","12.3000000000E1","012.300000000E1","0012.30000000E1","00012.3000000E1","000012.300000E1","0000012.30000E1","00000012.3000E1","000000012.300E1","0000000012.30E1","00000000012.3E1","1.23000000000E2","01.2300000000E2","001.230000000E2","0001.23000000E2","00001.2300000E2","000001.230000E2","0000001.23000E2","00000001.2300E2","000000001.230E2","0000000001.23E2",".123000000000E3","0.12300000000E3","00.1230000000E3","000.123000000E3","0000.12300000E3","00000.1230000E3","000000.123000E3","0000000.12300E3","00000000.1230E3","000000000.123E3","1230.0000000E-1","01230.000000E-1","001230.00000E-1","0001230.0000E-1","00001230.000E-1","000001230.00E-1","0000001230.0E-1","00000001230.E-1","000000001230E-1","12300.000000E-2","012300.00000E-2","0012300.0000E-2","00012300.000E-2","000012300.00E-2","0000012300.0E-2","00000012300.E-2","000000012300E-2","123000.00000E-3","0123000.0000E-3","00123000.000E-3","000123000.00E-3","0000123000.0E-3","00000123000.E-3","000000123000E-3","1230000.0000E-4","01230000.000E-4","001230000.00E-4","0001230000.0E-4","00001230000.E-4","000001230000E-4","12300000.000E-5","123000000.00E-5","1230000000.0E-5","12300000000.E-5","123000000000E-5","123000000.00E-6","1230000000.0E-6","12300000000.E-6","123000000000E-6","1230000000.0E-7","12300000000.E-7","123000000000E-7","12300000000.E-8","123000000000E-8","123000000000E-9"
"-123.00"                        "-123.0000000000","-0123.000000000","-00123.00000000","-000123.0000000","-0000123.000000","-00000123.00000","-000000123.0000","-0000000123.000","-00000000123.00","-000000000123.0","-0000000000123.","-00000000000123","-123.00000000E0","-0123.0000000E0","-00123.000000E0","-000123.00000E0","-0000123.0000E0","-00000123.000E0","-000000123.00E0","-0000000123.0E0","-00000000123.E0","-000000000123E0","-12.300000000E1","-012.30000000E1","-0012.3000000E1","-00012.300000E1","-000012.30000E1","-0000012.3000E1","-00000012.300E1","-000000012.30E1","-0000000012.3E1","-1.2300000000E2","-01.230000000E2","-001.23000000E2","-0001.2300000E2","-00001.230000E2","-000001.23000E2","-0000001.2300E2","-00000001.230E2","-000000001.23E2","-.12300000000E3","-0.1230000000E3","-00.123000000E3","-000.12300000E3","-0000.1230000E3","-00000.123000E3","-000000.12300E3","-0000000.1230E3","-00000000.123E3","-1230.000000E-1","-01230.00000E-1","-001230.0000E-1","-0001230.000E-1","-00001230.00E-1","-000001230.0E-1","-0000001230.E-1","-00000001230E-1","-12300.00000E-2","-012300.0000E-2","-0012300.000E-2","-00012300.00E-2","-000012300.0E-2","-0000012300.E-2","-00000012300E-2","-123000.0000E-3","-0123000.000E-3","-00123000.00E-3","-000123000.0E-3","-0000123000.E-3","-00000123000E-3","-1230000.000E-4","-01230000.00E-4","-001230000.0E-4","-0001230000.E-4","-00001230000E-4","-12300000.00E-5","-123000000.0E-5","-1230000000.E-5","-12300000000E-5","-123000000.0E-6","-1230000000.E-6","-12300000000E-6","-1230000000.E-7","-12300000000E-7","-12300000000E-8"
```

***TODO: Fix the possible outputs of the other test cases as well:***

```java
"0.123"                          ".12300000000000"
"-0.123"                         "-.1230000000000"
"1.23"                           "1.2300000000000"
"-1.23"                          "-1.230000000000"
"0.000000000000001"              "10000000000E-25"
"0"                              "000000000000000"
```

All these test cases will use the output-length as `7` (and rounding mode `HALF_UP`):

```java
Input:                           Output:
"987654321987654321.987654321"   "9.88E17"
"-987654321987654321.987654321"  "-9.9E17"
"1234567891234567.123456789"     "1.23E15"
"-1234567891234567.123456789"    "-1.2E15"
"0.123456789123456789"           ".123457"
"-0.123456789123456789"          "-.12346"
"5.5555555555555555555555555"    "5.55556"
"-5.5555555555555555555555555"   "-5.5556"
"123456789123456"                "1.23E14"
"-123456789123456"               "-1.2E14"
"123.00"                         "0000123" or "01.23E2" or "1.230E2"
"-123.00"                        "-000123" or "-12.3E1"
"0.123"                          ".123000"
"-0.123"                         "-.12300"
"1.23"                           "1.23000"
"-1.23"                          "-1.2300"
"0.000000000000001"              "100E-17" or "1.0E-15"
"0"                              "0000000",".000000","0.00000","00.0000","000.000","0000.00","00000.0","000000.","0E12345","000E-98"",etc.,etc. :/
```

Comment: Suggest testcase: `"0.0000000001", 10 -> ".000000000"`, `"0", 10, "0000000000"`

Comment: @tsh Added (although I've used `n=15` instead of 10 so I could add it to the other list instead of creating two separated test cases for the `n=10`. Principle remains the same for your test cases, so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @tsh Your test case actually made me realize that `s="0.0000000001", n=10` should be `"100000E-15"` instead for the most accurate result. Will have to do some fixes to my reference implementation.

Comment: Why should it be `100E-17`, not `1.0E-15`? The rule makes me confusing.

Comment: @tsh `1.0E-15` would be allowed as well. I still have to change the rules after realizing that `0.00000` would be an incorrect result for `s="0.0000000001", n=7`, but both `100E-17` and `1.0E-15` are allowed, since they are of length `7` and retain the same exact value as `0.0000000001`. I currently don't have the time to revise the rules, test cases, and reference implementation unfortunately (and if I delete the Sandbox post temporarily I can't search back for it).

Comment: You say `this challenge asks for exactly 15 characters long` but you then have outputs of varying length. I assume you want the latter. I'm being pedantic, I know, but it's the only thing I can find to fix at the moment ;)

Comment: @Jono2906 I've changed the part at the output-section. I hope it's a bit clearer now?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it is clearer now. I mean, as I said, I was just being pedantic about things.

Comment: @Jono2906 Well, it was still a valid remark that I agree with, so thanks. :)

Comment: Just another thing: _Perhaps_ `The decimal string input is guaranteed to be valid and non-empty` should be `The decimal string input is guaranteed to be a valid float and non-empty`

Comment: @Jono2906 Textual there isn't a difference between `decimal/double/float`, though. I had the sentence in my head as "_the decimal string input is guaranteed to be (a) valid (decimal) and non-empty_". I could change it to that if it makes it clearer, but talking about `decimal` first and `float` after that is more confusing than clarifying imho. But if you indeed meant "_the decimal string input is guaranteed to be_ a _valid_ decimal _and non-empty_" I'll change it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yep, I indeed meant `decimal`. I've no clue why I said `float`.

Answer (score 1):

### Internal Truth Machine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

It's a [normal truth machine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Truth-machine) but instead of taking input, it uses the first character of the program. Thus, internal.

Example: `0abcd` prints 0 and halts, and `1abcd` prints 1 infinitely.

Comment: I do not quite understand what the challenge is.

Comment: I already put it at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198288/internal-truth-machine?noredirect=1#comment471725_198288

Answer (score 1):

#### Posted: [Find the Inverse Neighbor Pairs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198846/find-the-inverse-neighbor-pairs) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Answer (score 1):

## Balanced interval tree [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)

You will write [a balanced, online interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree).

- A function, method, or procedure that performs insertion into a query of intervals that overlap with an interval over a, b in `O(log n)` time, given that a is less than b, including:

  - intervals that fully enclose a, b
  - intervals fully within a, b
  - intervals that start to the left of a but end before b
  - intervals that start to the right of a but end after b
- A function, method, or procedure that performs insertion ov an arbitrary interval a,b into a data structure in `O(log n)` time
- Both O-bounds must hold after arbitrary series of insertions and queries

### Requirements

If you write non-method functions, your submission may take the data structure as a global variable or receive the data structure as the first parameter.

You must informally prove your submission falls within the required O-bounds or name the data structure your program implements. If the name of the data structure you are implementing is obscure, you may name the paper of the data structure.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the shortest length in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Recolour my Table (Abandoned)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Comment: Maybe try limiting the table format. Is it top down or sideways? Also can we assume that the original table color (or slight variation to a certain HSL difference, maybe) is the majority of the image?

Answer (score 1):

## floating-point error matters

Write a **expression** of **floating-point numbers** in any languages. When calculating the expression without floating-point errors (as what a human do), it should be 0. But with floating-point errors (as what happened in your language), it yield 1 instead.

- Floating-point numbers are some numbers which store a finite number digits (binary or decimal or in any other bases) of fraction, plus an exponent in computer. It may be IEEE 754, but not must be.
- Loss of precision due to integer types (which do not has a exponent) are not allowed in the expression. You are still allowed to include integers (or even other types) in your expression as long as operations such as rounding into an integer are not the root of errors.

Shortest codes win as code-golf.

---

Sandbox:

- Is there any duplicates here?
- Is asking for an expression instead of full program allowed?

Comment: Yes, you can *allow* expressions. Good fit for this one, imho.

Answer (score 1):

No title yet.

By Zekendorf's theorem every non-negative integer has a unique representation as the sum of Fibonacci numbers where no two numbers coincide or are adjacent.

In [The minimum fibonacci challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/) the challenge was to output the list of Fibonacci numbers. However, you can instead consider the list of coefficients of the sum \$ \small x_0F(2) + x_1F(3) + x_2F(4) + \ldots \$ (since \$ \small F(0) = 0 \$ and \$ \small F(1) = F(2) \$ never appear in the Zekendorf representation) and represent that as a binary number \$ \ldots x_2 x_1 x_0 \$, e.g. \$ \small 67 = \small 1F(2) + 0F(3) + 1F(4) + 0F(5) + 1F(6) + 0F(7) + 0F(8) + 0F(9) + 1F(10) \$ which we can represent using the binary number \$ \small 100010101 \$ or \$ \small 277 \$ in decimal.

We can readily convert the binary representation back into the original integer by calculating the sum of the relevant Fibonacci numbers. However, I would like you to, given an input integer \$ \small n \$, output the decimal integer whose binary representation encodes the Zekendorf representation of \$ \small n \$ in this way.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest function or program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I would clarify that your binary representation is "flipped", i.e. 0-extends infinitely to the left.

Comment: @JonathanFrech flipped in comparison to what?

Comment: @RGS I wrote the Fibonacci coefficients from left to right but the bits in the binary number from right to left and it wasn't so clear before.

Comment: Oh ok, but that still matches what we don in binary. I can also write `11 = 1 + 2 + 8` and \$11 = 1011_2\$ :) but sure, going for perfect clarity is better than trusting other people's common sense

Comment: @RGS Having to guess the specifications from a single example is not really common sense as it is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

## Find the most important character

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

The challenge is to write a program that outputs the most occurrent non-trivial* character in the input string, excluding these bracketing characters `()[]{}`.  A solution is scored by feeding the program's source into its input.  Bracketing characters are allowed in the program, but may not be selected by the program as the most occurrent character.  In cases where letters have the same percentile score, any of the characters can be returned, or all of them.

<strike>Write a program that has a maximal percentage of a single non-trivial* character, excluding these bracketing characters `()[]{}`.  Bracketing characters are allowed, but may not be selected as the highest-percentage character.  Answer is scored as by running the program, with the program's source as its own input.  In cases where letters have the same percentile score, any of the characters can be returned, or all of them.</strike>

*Non-trivial is defined in this case to be a character that contributes to the functionality of the program.  If the character can be removed without influencing how the program runs, it is a trivial character.

### Scoring

Score is determined as follows:

$$(\frac{n_{char}}{n_{total}}) * 100\% $$

With n<sub>char</sub> being the number of occurrences of that character in the input, and n<sub>total</sub> being the total number of non-trivial characters in the input.  With this scoring criteria, all scores should be within the range `(0,100]`

Highest scoring solution per language wins.

### Input

Solutions should take in any valid string as input.  Scoring is done using the program's source code as input(with all non-trivial charcters removed).

### Output

A single character with the highest percentage occurrence.  Each solution should be capable of outputting standard ASCII, as well as the language's codepage (if applicable).

### Errata

Creative solutions are encouraged.  Boring solutions with long padded strings substituted in for numbers are discouraged.  Standard loopholes are disallowed.

### Examples

Program:

`aabbbc`

Output:

`b`

---

Program:

`aabb`

Output:

`a` or `b` or `ab`

Comment: Since I don't see it mentioned, you may want to add we should aim for an as high as possible percentage as score.

Comment: And if I understand it correctly the input is the only possible input for the program? So it won't have to work for other inputs as well (outputting the 'most important' character of that input).

Comment: So something like [`'??` in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3d4eTAAA) (push "?" and output it, ignoring the input) would score 66.7%?

Comment: You are correct on aiming for the highest score. My intention was that the code should work on any inputs, however scoring is only done on the program source itself.

Comment: Ah ok, that indeed seems better. You may want to clarify that a bit, since at the Input section it now only mentions "_The program's source code_", hence my confusion.

Comment: You’re right, that bit is a tad vague. I will update when I get to work.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've edited the challenge to reflect these changes.  Does this better reflect the challenge?

Comment: Yep, that's indeed a lot clearer! :) One more question: can the input potentially contain any unicode character, or is it limited to just printable ASCII and/or the language's used codepage?

Comment: Hmm, well if the character isn't on the languages codepage then it likely wouldnt be used in a solution right?  I'd think that any character that the program can successfully output would be valid.

Comment: "_I'd think that any character that the program can successfully output would be valid._" This is different than having to support the entire codepage or extended ASCII, though. I.e. an answer in Unary/Lenguage using a single character and printing that single used character would score 100%, since the only possible input is any amount of that chosen character. And an answer in Whitespace would only have to support spaces, tabs, and newlines as potential input in that case. If that's your intention than it's fine by me, but it's different than allowing the entire codepage as input. :)

Comment: Ahh I see the distinction you are making.  I'd say that the program should at least be able to printout standard ASCII, as well as the languages codepage.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yep, that indeed sounds as a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Be second to last

This is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge with a game with a clear winning strategy, but the winner is not the one who comes in first, but the one who comes in second to last! While losing is easy (just throw every game), just barely not losing is quite a task.

### The Game

The bots will be made to play games of normal [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) against each other. The rules are as follows:

- The board consists of a list of unsigned integers
- In alternating turns, the players reduce one non-zero element by an amount of their choosing, as long as the element is not negative afterwards
- The player who reduces the list to all entries being 0 wins

The length of the Nim list and its entries will be randomly determined for each game.

### The Tournament

All bots will compete against each other in a Danish-Style tournament:

- Initially, players are assigned positions in a list randomly
- After each round, the list is sorted by the amount of wins with an order-preserving method
- In each round, the players with the odd numbers play against those with the following even numbers (so 1st against 2nd, 3rd against 4th, and so forth)
- If the number of players is odd, the one in the middle position has a bye and is given 1 win without playing.
- The tournament ends after \$\lceil \log_{2}(N_{Players}) \rceil\$ (Binary logarithm of the number of players, rounded up) rounds.

The player in the second to last position of the list counts as the total winner of the tournament.

### King of the Hill

Each time the contest is run, 100 tournaments are played. The bots with the highest number of being second to last is the overall winner.

## Challenge Rules

- Each bot is a **Python 3** class implementing the following functions:

  - `__init__(ID, n)` passes the bot its randomly assigned ID for this tournament, and the total number of players.
  - `nim(self,list)` which takes in the Nim board state and returns a tuple `(index, amount)`, specifying from which list index to subtract what number. This function is repeatedly called during each game of Nim played, until a winner has been determined.
  - `rank(self,IDs,scores)` which takes in the current order of ranking in the tournament, and the list of scores of each bot, *ordered by ID*. It returns nothing. This will be called for each bot after each round of tournament, as well as before the first round, to provide the ranking information if the bot requires it.
- Bots are explicitly allowed to implement further functions and store data for private use. Bots will only be deleted and re-initialized after each full tournament.
- Programming meta-effects are forbidden, meaning any attempts to directly access other bots' code, the Controller's code, causing Exceptions or similar. Any bot doing so is disqualified until fixed.
- The following will also be set up to cause Exceptions:

  - `nim` returning an index of which the element is already 0
  - `nim` return an amount larger than the element at that index
- Other languages are allowed only in case they can be easily converted to Python 3.
- Class names have to be unique
- Multiple bots per person are allowed, but only the latest version will be taken of iteratively updated bots.
- As per [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), copies of bots are not allowed. This includes bots who differ from other bots only by a trivial change in strategy (e.g. a change in the pseudorandom seed).

### Controller and Examples

Watch this space.

Comment: this sounds fun! I have no idea how it fits this community, but I can't wait to see this in the main site!

Comment: @RGS king-of-the-hill challenges are common -- not all challenges have to be code-golf.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I know not everything has to be code golf, I'm just saying that in the little time I've been active, I've never seen a KotH challenge

Comment: Me neither. This sounds great!

Answer (score 1):

Comment: What happens if all integers are equally probable? Is that answer disqualified? Or does it score `infinity`? I also take it that there is a factor of randomness here, so perhaps you could mention that.

Comment: Of course, I may have missed the mark completely. Are we required to create our own scale of randomness (i.e. our own deviation from uniform randomness if that makes sense)?

Comment: If all integers are equally probably, wouldn't that give a score of effectively 0? (probability of 1/Integer.Max for the "most frequently occuring", which could be any of the integers)?

Comment: @Lyxal It is mathematically impossible for all integers to have equal probability.

Comment: This seems easy to score arbitrarily close to zero. For example, keep generating a random number from 1 to N until you get a 1, and count how many tries it takes before you succeed. To include negative outputs, pick a random sign. Make N large and the score tends to 0.

Comment: @xnor There is a byte limit which stops "arbitrarily close" formulations.  Did you miss this or am I missing what you are suggesting?

Comment: You're right, the byte limit stops you from actually getting arbitrarily close to 0. But, I expect there to be plenty of room in 100 bytes to stuff in some ginormous number bust-beaver style, at least in fairly compact languages. So, I think this challenge will mostly come down to "what's the biggest number you can express in 100-X bytes" where X is however many bytes the random part takes.

Comment: My thought is that there are a number of possible things that you would be able to use as the random part each with different drawbacks and strengths.  In my mind the challenge is sort of coming up with the random part that best fits the language.  There is definitely going to be a big number component to this that is important, but since that has mostly been explored in other challenges I would expect borrowing there.

Comment: What do you think then about the challenge being just to generate a random integer so that each one has nonzero probability? I think that as is, the big number generation is so important to the score that it makes this a chameleon challenge.

Comment: Alternatively, the "big number" N could be an input, and you stipulate that as N grows, the maximum chance of any integer to be chosen must approach zero.

Comment: @xnor I think that I am pretty happy with the challenge as is.  I prefer the current challenge over the suggested challenges since this one I feel has an incentive to loosen the distribution whereas I do not feel the others do.  The big number generation is important, but I consider that as a more general technique.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about loosening the distribution. I'm envisioning solutions in a golfing language to be about 7 bytes of "take a number N and make a flat random distribution based on it" and 93 bytes of "generate a huge N". For regular languages with a `random()` function, maybe split it 25 bytes / 75 bytes. Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't really see a viable strategy that isn't effectively the N-input challenge I suggested but with big number generation code copy-pasted in for N. Do you think there is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104468/discussion-between-xnor-and-post-rock-garf-hunter).

Comment: I would allow for some entropy input to give pure languages a chance.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I would like to but it is a little difficult for entropy to make it work.  If you have a concrete idea for how I might fairly introduce entropy, I am open to ideas.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter You could possibly allow a time parameter and require "reasonable" time independence of the solution.

Comment: @JonathanFrech A time parameter has a few issues.  It is basically just an integer so we need it to be unbounded (otherwise only a finite number of outputs can be attained)  and on top of that we need to specify a distribution on the input for a distribution on the output to make sense.  There is not really a clear best distribution for time, even harder is one that is not exploitable to the extent it trivializes the challenge.

Comment: However, does this problem not already exist, just hidden? Most implementations use an RNG with finite, not provably controllable entropy assumed to be distributed uniformly.

Comment: What score would [this C program](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185M7cgv6jEpiQzN1Uvw44rNzEzT0OzuqAoM68kTUNJNUVJpygxL0WjGEyCVGn4hfr4aAKBde3//wA) get?

Comment: @JonathanFrech To answer your first question, you can get unbounded entropy by repeatedly sampling the time (variations in compute time can make successive samples effectively independent of the initial) but taking a single time prevents you from sampling more than once. To answer your second question since C has bounded integer size there are integers that that will not output making it not a valid answer.

Comment: I see ... What language would be viable in the sense that it allows for an implementation of a program with codomain \$\mathbb{Z}\$?

Comment: @JonathanFrech One example would be Haskell which has unbound integers.  Many languages have these.  But even C can output an arbitrary stream of digits as a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104879/discussion-between-jonathan-frech-and-post-rock-garf-hunter).

Comment: You could consider "Love all integers equally" or "All numbers are interesting" or something for sillier challenge names. I think this works pretty well as-is. However, because of the optional input, I would recommend reiterating that the input could also be assumed to be empty (as a variant of no input). A few languages can get hung up on that (though I can't think of one I'd like to use for this).

Answer (score 1):

### Shift the digits [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [restricted-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-time)

Here, **x** (supplied as input) and **n** (the result of your computation) are both positive integers. `n * x = n shifted`. Find n.

Here's an example of shifting:

```
123456789 -> 912345678
abcdefghi -> iabcdefgh (letters = any 0~9 digit)
123       -> 312
```

### Rules

- Preceding zeros count after shifting. If the number is `10` and is multiplied by `0.1` (`0.1` isn't a valid input), the result is `1`, which isn't equal to `01` (`10` after shifting).
- Your code has to run on [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#) without timing out.
- If your number only has one digit, the shifted result is your number:

```
1 -> 1
4 -> 4
9 -> 9
```

### Test cases

Just to show that it's possible ...

```
9 -> 10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719
(In this test case, x = 9 and n = 10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719.
n shifted = n * x =              91011235955056179775280898876404494382022471)
```

Don't believe it? [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lcsxDoAwCADA3VeQuKiJCVAosPgeXWpjuvh6fIO3X3/HebeS2Z@rjYWQiIuGKmolCzNlRw93q4IiIcUZmcUotlinGfYDIH60zA8)

Comment: Is this the point of the challenge: "you hardcode any number you want in your code, I give you a number as input, you multiply your number by mine and right shift it once"?

Comment: @Lyxal The challenge should be self-explanatory. Can you understand it now?

Comment: Aha! So it's "x * n = x shifted, find n". I get it now!

Comment: I feel there is something I'm missing. Are you going to give as input only numbers that have a multiple that corresponds to said shifting?

Comment: I've been doing some thinking and I believe that asking to find the smallest possible _integer_ is impossible for numbers which aren't all the same digit. Some test cases would be helpful.

Comment: I've seen a really large integer (in a book) that shifts itself right once after being multiplied by 9. If that's really neccecary I'd try to type it here.

Comment: @Lyxal It's possible, see my test case.

Comment: @RGS I'm going to give any number that has a multiple; after division of that multiple by that number, the result will be the reverse of the shifting of the number. (I've changed my challenge since Lyxal "got" the formula.)

Answer (score 1):

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199654/finding-radical-ideals)

Answer (score 1):

### [Approximate Alternating Triangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200554/alternating-triangles)

Comment: I think your added explanation is good, though I admit I still don't see how the resulting image is a triangle. It may just be me, but maybe it would be easier to see if provided a drawing?

Comment: Ah, I see, but why `\\`` (sorry comment markdown is messing that up, just the one backslash...) on the left and not `|`? You could also try naming it "approximate alternating triangles" or something.

Comment: _look less like a triangle_ Why do you want to make it look _less than a triangle? Why not `|` to make it look more like a triangle?

Answer (score 1):

## [Japanese Encoding Conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200767/japanese-encoding-conversion) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoding)

Comment: I think switching between hex and decimal in the definitions is more likely to cause confusion than sticking to just one of them. I think you also don't indicate that the tuples you define are bytes that are concatenated to the final result. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't the clipping mean converting from shift JIS is ambiguous? Separately, you can use `\left` and `\right` to make your brackets the right height.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman For the Shift_JIS case, the range used is `[0x81-0x9F,0xE0-0xEF]` for the first byte and `[0x40-0x7E, 0x80-0xFC]` for the second byte, which is of size precisely 8,836. Since 区 won't exceed 128, and the starting points of 点 in both cases are separated by 95, the first case won't overlap with the second.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I wrote kuten in decimal and bytes in hexadecimal because they were so defined; edited to only show in decimal, but keep accepting both decimal and hexadecimal input/output form.

Comment: Ah yes, I see where I made an error now. I think the rewrite you did makes it easier to read. I don't see anything else, though of course I don't speak for everyone. Good luck!

Comment: Typo: `monas` should be `moras`.

Answer (score 1):

### Making Minimial Memory Masterpieces

In this challenge you will be asked to write a small computer program to paint an approximation of the painting [*Fine Wind, Clear Morning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_Wind,_Clear_Morning).

### Your submission

In this challenge we are going to start with a blank canvas.  We are going to add an "ant" in the top left corner.  You will be telling the ant how to paint the picture by writing its brain.

An ant is a simple creature, at a given time it knows two things.

- Some memories that it has
- The color of the pixel it is currently standing on

And at every step the ant consults these two things it knows and then

1. Draws one pixel of any color where it is standing
2. Moves one pixel in a cardinal direction
3. Replaces its all of its memory

The ant can thus be thought of as a function which takes a color and a value and spits out a color, a value and a cardinal direction.

For example here is the brain of an ant that draws a zigzag pattern in red

\$
  f(c,m) = \left\{\begin{matrix}(\mathrm{Red}, & \mathrm{South}, & 1) & \mathrm{if} & m = 0\\
(\mathrm{Red}, & \mathrm{East}, & 0) & \mathrm{if} & m = 1\end{matrix}\right.
\$

However our canvas is not infinite, so this ant would run into a border eventually.  We will stop the ant if it tries to move off, by canceling its move and leaving it on the square it is on.  You are free to use this behavior to your advantage.

The one issue here is that currently the ant will never stop, it will just keep painting forever.  Which is why ants come with a builtin kill switch.  When an ant's memories are equal to an exact value the ant explodes or something, ending the drawing.

Your submission will thus consist of 3 things

- The starting memory for your ant
- A description of the ant's function (more on this later)
- The ending memory for your ant

### Scoring

The goal of this challenge is to have the ant that requires the least memory to operate.  We will count this by the number of different states your ant's memory can have.

Thus to score your answer you should run it on the canvas provided.  Once the ant has finished your score will be the total number of distinct memories used by your ant through the process.  We will include the initial memory even if it does not appear again, but you should not count the ending memory (the one that kills the ant).

The lowest score will be the winner.

### The painting

*The painting will be a low resolution version of the one from the wikipedium.  It will use 3 bit color resolution.*

*I will decide on the exact specific sizes and make the image in a bit.*

A valid answer must produce this image exactly when run on the canvas.

### Verification Tool

*I will make a tool for running and verifying programs, using a standardized format.  It will be runnable in browser.*

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Interesting challenge, looks solid. Will there always be at least one empty column between lines or lane dividers, as seems to be in all examples?

Comment: With your new clarification, can there be two adjacent lines? Also, can there be an input with just one line, or just empty space? Are trailing empty spaces a possibility?

Comment: I meant in the input, but I guess whether the output can add or omit them could also be a question.

Comment: Yes, I think you answered everything. So, if I got this right, I think this is a uniquely-matching regex of all valid inputs as sequences of columns, with `e,l,d` indicating empty, lane, and divider: `e*(le(e|d)*e|le|l)*le*|e*`.

Comment: @xnor Took a little work to analyze but I think it is.

Answer (score 1):

### Golf yourself a *real* calculator [draft] [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

We will only cover the characters(`0123456789+-*/=%√±`) in our tutorial.

#### The `=` operations

Unlike most desktop calculators, our household calculator is a *tacit* language. Therefore it is able to do a lot more than other infix calculators.

Take a simple calculation as an example. The non-scientific calculator does not have the exponentiation operator. What do you do to calculate 2^5?

```
2*2====
```

However, there's a shortcut for doing that. Since 2 is already in the expression buffer, you can simply do

```
2*====
```

The calculator automatically fills in the current expression during the inputting.

Here is a demonstration of how this works:

```
(A template for easy copy&paste.

Pressed Key      : 
Expression buffer: 
Output buffer    : 
)

Pressed Key      : 2
Expression buffer: 2
Output buffer    : 2

Pressed Key      : *
Expression buffer: 2 *
Output buffer    : 2

Pressed Key      : =
Expression buffer: * 2
Output buffer    : 4

Pressed Key      : =
Expression buffer: * 2
Output buffer    : 8

Pressed Key      : =
Expression buffer: * 2
Output buffer    : 16

Pressed Key      : =
Expression buffer: * 2
Output buffer    : 32
```

### Implicit 0 before calculation

Suppose you enterede the following expression:

```
*1
```

Now, don't get me wrong, the household calculator of course doesn't have pointers. So, why doesn't it raise a syntax error though? (The output is `0` by the way.) Here's why.

> The calculator initially has the expression starting at `0`, therefore it prepends a 0 to the expression. Therefore the full form of our expression is:
>
> ```
> 0*1
> ```

### What we've learned so far

- The output buffer is a part of the calculator storing the latest-evaluated integer. All entered numbers get appended to the output buffer as well as the expression buffer.
- The expression buffer is a part of the calculator storing the latest instruction. After a `=` operator, it stores the latest applied expression for later application.
- The `=` operator tries to evaluate the instruction buffer. If that's a syntax error, it tries to evaluate that concatenated the output buffer. If that still fails, it tries to evaluate the output buffer concatenated with the instruction buffer. After that operation, the expression starting from the newest-entered dyadic operator is saved in the expression buffer.

Comment: [Relevant esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User_talk:A)

Answer (score 1):

## Is this a Freeman Dyson Number?

**Background**

From this [Popular Mechanics article](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/math/a31153757/riddles-brain-teasers-logic-puzzles/)

> One day, in a gathering of top scientists, one of them wondered out
>   loud whether there exists an integer that you could exactly double by
>   moving its last digit to its front. For instance, 265 would satisfy
>   this if 526 were its exact double – which it isn’t. After apparently
>   just five seconds, Dyson responded, “Of course there is, but the
>   smallest such number has 18 digits.”

**Challenge**
Write a program that, when given a base ten number that is at least 18 digits long, moves the last digit to the front and checks if it is doubled as a result.

**I/O**
Input can be any 18 (or longer) digit integer. Any leading digit must be larger than zero.

**Output**
 The original number with the Dyson transform (last digit moved to the front) and any truthy/falsey value (if that's a digit, it must have a delimiter).

**Test Cases/Sample I/O**

```
111111111111111111 -> 111111111111111111,false
100000000000000002 -> 210000000000000000 **F**
123456789123456789 -> [912345678912345678,0]
42105263157894736842 -> 24210526315789473684
808080808080808080808080808016 - 680808080808080808080808080801-NO
246802468024680246802468024680246802 -> false224680246802468024680246802468024680
105263157894736842 -> true,210526315789473684
315789473684210526 -> (T:5315789473684210526)
26315789473684210526315789473684210 -> 52631578947368421052631578947368421

etc...
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes (by language) wins.

Comment: I would specify that you are talking about decimal digits.

Comment: @JonathanFrech, Do you mean base 10?

Comment: I think one issue here is how to verify that the specific action of moving the digit from back-to-front, and then subsequently checking for doubling, actually happened. Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Yes, you should specify that this is in base 10.

Comment: @ouflak Yes, I mean base ten. One often hears for example "binary digits", so the term "digits" is in my opinion not clearly defined to mean base ten.

Comment: @JonathanFrech, @ S.S. Anne, The reason why I haven't immediately made the change is because I hadn't considered the idea of different number bases, and I'm really liking the idea of a challenge that in fact does include either various number bases, or a specific challenge for binary and this separate challenge for base ten. Mulling it over now. This would mean I'd have to figure out some binary test cases....

Comment: In binary doubling a number is adding 0 to the end of it, so unless you allow leading 0s it's not possible, otherwise it's correct iff the number starts with a 0

Comment: @CommandMaster, Yes! For binary, you would have to allow, even implicitly, a leading zero. The most obvious example is '1', which is really '01', which when the '1' is moved to the front becomes '10'. Don't see how you can get around that. It would be a different challenge. The number base thing has got me thinking.

Comment: Here are some suggestions: Make it a decision-problem (e.g. returning the Dyson transform *and* the Truthy/Falsey value is a bit unnecessary). Keep the sample IO consistent (I get that you want to show the variation in possible output formats, but it would be easier to verify cases if the format were consistent).

Answer (score 1):

## RRE numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given a single floating-point number (which can potentially be taken as a string), output whether this decimal is an RRE number.

## RRE complement for the input number

Say your input is `3.14`.

1. *Replace* the decimal point by the fraction bar. `3/14`
2. *Reciprocal* the fraction. `14/3`
3. *Evaluate* the fraction. `4.666...`
4. Round the decimal point to the same length as the input. `4.67`
5. If the absolute difference between the input and the output is below 2, it's an RRE number. Otherwise, it isn't an RRE number.

## Specification

1. Programs are allowed to give wrong output if the absolute difference is very close to 2.
2. The integral part of the decimal is *always* nonzero.
3. Truthy/Falsy outputs follows the language's convention, or exactly one value for truthy and another for falsy.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##ZY7BDoIwEETvfEXTC20iKy1wkOiXGA8YSsSQliyLwa@vRQ8YOqfNm5ndHd/0cLbwvjUdQzRikXXCgpBd2ALTOPQkOHD5hRSgeTWDSI8pPF1vBV7rOlM3ufnoZtsKOgxmdTcPDc1oWXOfRDe4hsKl7DeQlGedJCP2lsT6A1eQ81D7IxpOO1KAKneoykFXuYqqUTCgVfHG/UIFShcxrKIbZQgG5v0H) is a sample program I use to generate the test cases.

```
1.0     -> True
2.9     -> True
3.14    -> True
50.2501 -> True
2.14    -> False
2.11111 -> False
3.1     -> False
51.123  -> False
51.51   -> False
24.12   -> False
```

Comment: 1) Rounding `4.666...` to two decimal places gives `4.67`. 2) Floating-point numbers are always subject to precision issues. I think it's best to let the programs take a string representation as input, and state that "programs are allowed to give wrong output if the absolute difference is very close to 2". 3) If the integral part is 0, the algorithm will invoke division by 0. Is handling it part of the challenge?

Comment: 4) For truthy/falsy, it currently reads like I can output the input as-is and say "the program's output format is a RRE number for truthy, a non-RRE number for falsy". What I use is "truthy/falsy following the language's convention, or exactly one value for truthy and another for falsy".

Comment: I don't see how restricted source will fit here. Btw, a big truthy test case: `50.2501`

Comment: @Bubbler Ahh, the challenge is just about checking whether the square of the integral part is close to the the decimal part. Should I post it?

Answer (score 1):

## Modify The Stack [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203252/modify-the-stack)

Comment: Specifying that the *first* element is the top of the stack could help understanding the challenge a lot. Can we use some other values instead of the stack elements `a, b, c` and/or the commands `s, d, t`? Also, the operation `a b c -> b c a` is often called `rotate` or `roll`.

Comment: For test cases: `a c b` is `tts`. `a b a b c` can be done with `dtdtt` or `dtdts`.

Comment: thanks, but `dtdtt` and `dtdts` doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I had the `t` operation mistaken, but your `tdtsdt` doesn't work either. The first operation should be `s`.

Comment: right, I fixed that

Comment: I don't think the test cases are very helpful here until they are actually proven optimal... Do you really want to require input validation? If so, it is probably a very bad idea to post this without writing a reference implementation to make sure it's possible *and* not too annoying. (besides: I silently downvoted before because I simply dislike the idea, and not because of some specification issues, so I had nothing to comment)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Sandbox is all about *feedback*. Silent downvotes don't help the challenge writer and the community. If you don't like the whole idea, you could say so in the comments in the first place (preferably with *why* you think that way), and then the challenge writer could consider to rewrite it or abandon it and try out something different.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bit delivery in Bin City](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203563/9481) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

*posted*

Comment: It could help a lot to add an illustration for small test cases (how to move each bit in the input to the output), and some test cases with more bytes (both even and odd). Other than that, looks good to me.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks for the feedback. How's it now?

Comment: Perfect, and +1 for reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## Are these the same time? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## Context

When asked about the time (i.e. hours and minutes), people naturally reply with any one of a given set of fairly common sentences:

- (A) it is `M` past `H`
- (B) it is `M` to `H`
- (C) it is `H` minus `M`

Where `M` above refers to some amount of minutes and `H` to some amount of hours. Concrete corresponding examples, all referring to the time `3:40 pm`:

- (A) it is 40 past 3
- (B) it is 20 to 4
- (C) it is 4 minus 20

## Task

Given two of these sentences, output a Truthy value if they represent the same time and a Falsy value if they do not.

## Input

Your input will be two sentences of the above, where references to minutes will always be rounded to the nearest multiple of 5 (i.e. the minutes will always be one of `5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 50, 55`.

Because all sentences start with `"it is "` you may ommit that from your input sentences.

## Output

A Truthy value if the two times are the same, a Falsy value otherwise.

## Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##fZJRa4MwFIXf@ysu2YMJVbGr7KHgQGF/YOxBKHuQNe3u0Cgmbu2vdzGJzlJXn/Sec77IuWku6rMW274/8CM0hVQ09TO2W4F@HiBtT13FhQL5UzQNihMcO/GhsBahc7yEpxDiyERhC8EzbHdxZMSWq64VsM/89H21GviqvqK/GoPUjmDjw1MUaN@M@hjpAMTLzL@EIVcoOrkMT501u4LHNjIcssSfhQwfD7oFVJfZEZPVH02KlyVNnZxDAmkomxIV9VABSvDYfmN/oqoPXOuEmC88ArEFEkABuQWMkNxBRgub1JEyzC2Jl4ala7tPGgy3HFVfUWxB90HOc8sywoiT/L/8QnKs2obPejQoa0LJ2vO98KtGQXO2JozM18C/i5KemV2ELCr@hhW/3ZZbUZKYl4z1TYtC0SlA7KamC018N3GXkTDW/wI) is a sample program for checking the test cases.

## Sandbox

Should the minutes and hours in the input com as integers instead of English words?

Comment: Interesting challenge. Yes, the minutes and hours in the input should come as integers. Otherwise, this becomes a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214) that appears to be about parsing relation words, but actually is about parsing English numbers. I think you can make the challenge more interesting by adding (D) it is `H` `M`. Please address 1) how to distinguish AM/PM or that we don't need to, 2) how to deal with roll-overs like "5 to 0", and 3) if `H` and `M` have upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I kid you not, I have _never_ heard any one call it "H minus M". Still, I agree with @Adám that y'all need to ensure that input and output formats are what I like to call "reasonable and convenient", with extra emphasis on the "convenient" part.

Comment: @Lyxal Me neither. But actually, that can be fixed by changing "minus" to "in", as in "4 in 20 [minutes]"

Comment: An alternative you might consider to checking if two sentences represent equal times, is to have code take just one and produce any "canonical form" of it, such that the canonical form can be anything where two inputs give the same canonical form if and only if they are equal.

Comment: @petStorm thanks for your edit but I would prefer if you did not edit any reference programs into my sandboxed posts (you may comment with a TIO link) nor edited the challenge to cope with the feedback I get from commenters. The feedback is very good and I will take care of it, but I prefer to do it myself so I can do the changes I see necessary: e.g. if I am accepting hours and minutes as integers, I no longer want the minutes to be in the set `5, 10, 15, ..., 55`.

Answer (score 1):

## \$\Theta(N\cdot\sqrt N)\$ sort [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

The challenge is to write a program that sorts an array of distinct positive integers in ascending order. You may input the array and output the result using the default IO methods.

However, the worst-case time complexity of the algorithm used must be \$\Theta(N \cdot \sqrt N)\$, where \$N\$ is the length of the input array.

You may not assume your built-in sorting functions to have any time complexity in particular. While you can implement a fast (e.g. \$O(N \log N)\$) sort and then perform pointless operations to increase the complexity, direct algorithms exist.

This question is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

### Sandbox stuff

I have noticed that a possible solution is, for example, to create a sorted multiset from the array and read it back. I would probably like to disallow that. Is there a way to achieve that without making the validity criteria subjective?

Comment: I feel like this will be answered by implementing sorting efficiently, then doing something pointless for the required number of steps.

Comment: @xnor That would involve implementing a O(n log n) sort or radix sort, which can be more complicated than a O(n*sqrt(n)) algorithm. There's, for example, a gap sequence that results in O(n * sqrt(n)) complexity for Shellsort.

Answer (score 1):

## Similar Numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203185/another-similar-number)

Answer (score 1):

## Compactify the input [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203387/compactify-the-input)

Comment: Off topic: BASIC programmers were often recommended to name their variables this way.

Comment: I agree that it's better to compress a single word instead.

Comment: hmm ok, I'll do that

Comment: I think the mention of compression and natural language is misleading, since it leads the reader to expect some compression based on the statistical properties of text.

Comment: hmm ok, do you have an idea for a better name?

Comment: Do you think `Compactify the name` is a good idea?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23176001/12188239).

Comment: yes, I like that name, maybe `Compactify the input` though? As it doesn't have to be a name

Comment: I like `Compactify the input`

Comment: Just an FYI, the regex `\B[aeiou]` matches each character to be removed. You may receive a lot of answers that are basically just that.

Answer (score 1):

## How Many Ways To Empty The Glove Box?

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203343/how-many-ways-to-empty-the-glove-box)

Answer (score 1):

## Compress Numbers

Write two programs, a compressor and a decompressor.

### The compressor

- The compressor will accept a sequence of integers of any value from 0 to 2<sup>63</sup>-1, expressed in any convenient format.
- You may specify the required format as long as any arbitrary sequence of integers in the required range may be expressed in this format.
- Behaviour is undefined for any input that does not conform to your required format.
- The output will be a self contained sequence of bytes.

### The decompressor

- The input will be an unmodified sequence of bytes produced by a valid input to the compressor.
- Behaviour is undefined for any other sequences of bytes.
- The output will be the same input to the compressor program that produced the provided sequence of bytes.

### Judging

The winning entry will be the valid entry that produces the smallest intermediate sequence of bytes for a sequence of integers that will be produced by the question setter that will be revealed after some number of entries have been submitted and only entries submitted prior to that reveal will be eligible to win.

This sequence will be generated by joining these following sequences into a single sequence and then randomly shuffling that single sequence.

- 1000 repetitions of the same randomly selected number from 0 to 9.
- 1000 repetitions of the same randomly selected number from 2<sup>62</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>-1.
- For each x in (8, 16, 32, 63):

  - 1000 random numbers from 0 to 2<sup>x</sup>-1.

The question setter will answer the challenge with GZIP/GUNZIP at the highest compression setting with no additional processing. If that entry wins, the glory of winning will belong to the authors of GZIP.

### Tie-Breaker

If two or more entries produce produce byte sequences of the same size, the following criteria will decide the winner:

1. If one of those entries is the GZIP entry posted by the question setter, that entry will win.
2. The entry with the highest voting score wins.
3. The entry posted first wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Reconstruct an image from columns [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

You are given an image with all pixel-wide columns shuffled. The challenge is to attempt to reconstruct the image.

[image gallery of varying difficulties]

### Sandbox stuff

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) (probably asking for fewest inversions)?

Random thought: if rearranging the pixels was similar to the assignment problem, this seems to be similar to the traveling salesman problem.

Answer (score 1):

### A065825 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

(This is [A065825](https://oeis.org/A065825).) The [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) defaults apply, so you can pick another format other than this one.

Given an input integer `n`, find the smallest number `k` so that there exists an n-item subset of `{1,...,k}` where no three items form an arithmetic progression.

### Procedure

Here, we calculate `A065825(9)`.

We assume you have already looped from 1 to 19, and `k`=20 (it's just an example).

#### 1. Generate a range from 1 to k.

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

#### 2. Pick `n` items from that sequence, following the original order of the sequence.

```
[1 2 6 7 9 14 15 18 20]
```

#### 3. No 3 items form an arithmetic progression.

If a sequence has arithmetic progression, it basically means the sequence has the same step between every two consecutive items.

For example, the sequence of positive even numbers (`[2 4 6 8 ...]`) has a consistent step (i.e. `4-2=2`, and `6-4=2`, etc.), so it has arithmetic progression.

The Fibonacci sequence (`[1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...]`) does not have arithmetic progression, since it does not have a consistent step. (`3-2=1`, `5-3=2`, `8-5=3`, etc.)

As an example, let's pick 3 items from our generated sequence.

```
[1 2 6 [7 9 14] 15 18 20]
```

The picked 3-item sequence does not have arithmetic progression, since the differences are respectively `9-7=2` and `14-9=5`.

This has to apply to **every 3-item pair**:

```
[[1 2 6] 7 9 14 15 18 20] (2 -1 =1, 6 -2 =4)
[1 [2 6 7] 9 14 15 18 20] (6 -2 =4, 7 -6 =1)
[1 2 [6 7 9] 14 15 18 20] (7 -6 =1, 9 -7 =2)
[1 2 6 [7 9 14] 15 18 20] (9 -7 =2, 14-9 =5)
[1 2 6 7 [9 14 15] 18 20] (14-9 =5, 15-14=1)
[1 2 6 7 9 [14 15 18] 20] (15-14=1, 18-15=3)
[1 2 6 7 9 14 [15 18 20]] (18-15=3, 20-18=2)
```

Here are some examples of picking non-consecutive items from the output sequence:

```
[1 [2] 6 [7] 9 [14] 15 18 20] (7-2=5,14-7=7)
[[1] 2 6 [7] [9] 14 15 18 20] (7-1=6,9 -7=2)
```

If the above is satisfied for `k`, then `k` is a valid output for `A065825(9)`.

### Meta

Do you think this challenge should be splitted into separate challenges? It seems that it is a single sequence on OEIS.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSTMOmScO5ypLDpjPDuc61wqXDi33DoF99Z8SAfdC9//83) is a reference program I use to check my test cases.

```
n       a(n)
1       1
2       2
3       4
4       5
5       9
6       11
7       13
8       14
9       20
```

Answer (score 1):

## Are these two DFAs equivalent?

Two Deterministic Finite Automata or [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) can be checked to see if they accept same set of strings in polynomial time.  See [section 3.3 of this](https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7944&context=theses) for a long list of methods and this [SO](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81813/is-the-equality-of-two-dfas-a-decidable-problem) question/answer for a much shorter list.

**Input**

Your input will be two [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). In order to be able to test your code, it needs to be able to handle DFAs in the following format. This is taken  directly from [GAP](https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7944&context=theses) (and slightly simplified).

```
Automaton( Type, Size, Alphabet, TransitionTable, Initial, Accepting )
```

For the input, Type will always be "det".  Size is a positive integer representing the number of states of the automaton. Alphabet is the number of letters of the alphabet. TransitionTable is the transition matrix. The entries are non-negative integers not greater than the size of the automaton are also allowed. Initial and Accepting are, respectively, the lists of initial and accepting states.

For example:

```
Automaton("det",4,2,[ [ 1, 3, 4, 0 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ],[ 3 ],[ 2, 3, 4 ])
```

This has transition table:

```
   |  1  2  3  4  
-----------------
 a |  1  3  4     
 b |  1  2  3  4  
Initial state:    [ 3 ]
Accepting states: [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

And diagram:

[image]

It is equivalent to:

```
Automaton("det",3,2,[ [ 1, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ],[ 2 ],[ 2, 3 ])
```

which has diagram:

[image]

A more complicated example:

```
Automaton("det",6,4,[ [ 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 4, 5, 6 ])
```

has diagram:

[image]

It is equivalent to:

```
Automaton("det",5,4,[ [ 2, 2, 2, 4, 5 ], [ 2, 2, 3, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 2, 3, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 2, 5, 1, 4 ] ],[ 3 ],[ 1, 3 ])
```

with diagram:

[image]

## More example of equivalent DFAs

1.

```
Automaton("det",18,4,[ [ 2, 2, 6, 10, 2, 6, 7, 16, 14, 10, 18, 14, 7, 14, 15, 16, 7, 18 ], [ 3, 3, 7, 11, 3, 7, 15, 11, 7, 17, 15, 18\
, 18, 7, 15, 17, 15, 15 ], [ 4, 4, 8, 7, 4, 13, 15, 15, 16, 7, 8, 7, 15, 7, 15, 15, 16, 13 ], [ 5, 5, 9, 12, 5, 14, 7, 13, 9, 14, 17, 12, \
13, 14, 15, 7, 17, 7 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18 ])
```

```
Automaton("det",16,"abcd",[ [ 1, 2, 15, 15, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 2, 16, 12, 12, 16, 15, 16 ], [ 1, 3, 1, 7, 9, 15, 1, 1, 15, 8, 7, 3, 8, 15, 1, \
15 ], [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 13, 4, 4, 10, 10, 1, 15, 15, 15, 2, 1, 15 ], [ 1, 15, 3, 4, 5, 16, 15, 3, 14, 4, 11, 16, 11, 14, 15, 16 ] ],[ 5 ],[ 2,\
 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ])
```

  2.

```
Automaton("det",50,4,[ [ 2, 2, 9, 13, 17, 9, 13, 17, 9, 24, 28, 30, 13, 33, 36, 30, 17, 9, 13, 9, 13, 39, 30, 24, 25, 44, 42, 28, 24, 30, 47, 39, 33, 50, 36, 36, 42, 46, 39, 25, 24, 42, 43, 44, 36, 46, 47, 42, 25, 50 ], [ 3, 6, 10, 14, 18, 10, 14, 20, 10, 25, 14, 10, 32, 34, 34, 38, 20, 10, 14, 10, 14, 38, 10, 25, 43, 34, 25, 45, 46, 10, 32, 49, 34, 43, 34, 49, 50, 50, 49, 50, 46, 25, 43, 49, 49, 50, 45, 50, 43, 43 ], [ 4, 7, 11, 15, 19, 11, 15, 21, 22, 26, 26, 31, 15, 11, 25, 15, 21, 11, 15, 11, 15, 40, 15, 40, 43, 43, 44, 26, 26, 15, 44, 31, 41, 26, 47, 25, 25, 22, 40, 43, 40, 25, 43, 43, 47, 41, 44, 44, 44, 40 ], [ 5, 8, 12, 16, 5, 12, 16, 8, 23, 27, 29, 12, 23, 35, 37, 16, 8, 12, 16, 12, 16, 41, 23, 42, 25, 40, 27, 27, 29, 23, 48, 45, 37, 49, 35, 42, 37, 48, 42, 40, 41, 42, 43, 25, 45, 37, 27, 48, 49, 25 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50 ])
```

```
Automaton("det",39,4,[ [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 24, 7, 8, 22, 20, 8, 32, 18, 18, 3, 19, 25, 18, 19, 20, 25, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25, 24, 23, 5, 2, 35, 32, 19, 19, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36 ], [ 1, 38, 1, 23, 15, 9, 11, 26, 23, 28, 26, 10, 9, 26, 1, 3, 22, 26, 3, 28, 22, 23, 1, 15, 3, 3, 15, 1, 28, 27, 10, 27, 23, 23, 38, 15, 28, 15, 28 ], [ 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 12, 6, 6, 31, 31, 37, 37, 30, 5, 5, 29, 37, 3, 21, 4, 21, 4, 4, 4, 29, 30, 29, 1, 5, 29, 37, 5, 3, 29, 3, 3, 2, 2 ], [ 1, 16, 3, 4, 3, 21, 7, 18, 33, 39, 14, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 34, 21, 34, 3, 19, 19, 16, 38, 15, 4, 33, 17, 18, 33, 34, 16, 19, 34, 38, 39 ] ],[ 7 ],[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 ])
```

3.

```
Automaton("det",288,4,[[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 6, 10, 14, 18, 25, 29, 33, 36, 40, 43, 46, 36, 53, 10, 14, 18, 10, 14, 18, 25, 29, 60, 36, 29, 67, 71, 75, 77, 81, 83, 87, 88, 90, 94, 40, 98, 46, 104, 108, 111, 46, 116, 120, 75, 123, 127, 129, 53, 10, 14, 131, 129, 71, 75, 136, 140, 143, 146, 87, 149, 75, 67, 68, 155, 153, 156, 159, 161, 163, 75, 165, 77, 170, 81, 172, 81, 67, 88, 123, 156, 146, 87, 88, 156, 90, 183, 186, 188, 87, 90, 183, 94, 192, 143, 197, 199, 116, 75, 104, 108, 204, 172, 108, 208, 120, 127, 159, 90, 199, 163, 159, 215, 156, 149, 120, 153, 217, 123, 218, 131, 221, 127, 159, 87, 123, 225, 88, 155, 67, 165, 136, 227, 143, 221, 123, 218, 221, 143, 68, 67, 88, 123, 127, 143, 217, 68, 67, 153, 154, 155, 156, 234, 235, 159, 120, 161, 237, 143, 217, 165, 143, 241, 199, 188, 242, 197, 75, 67, 165, 241, 217, 248, 250, 172, 146, 221, 161, 225, 234, 111, 186, 153, 75, 217, 75, 188, 192, 257, 188, 68, 120, 90, 186, 127, 90, 208, 146, 221, 259, 140, 120, 235, 208, 165, 262, 199, 188, 68, 120, 215, 267, 217, 218, 250, 83, 75, 165, 75, 215, 225, 208, 234, 71, 149, 153, 75, 235, 208, 234, 67, 265, 272, 233, 241, 143, 120, 242, 257, 155, 153, 143, 153, 248, 267, 250, 116, 120, 75, 237, 71, 235, 250, 163, 259, 227, 153, 262, 67, 75, 155, 233, 272, 265, 116, 241, 281, 272, 68, 149, 120, 155, 283, 163, 67, 208, 285, 265, 287, 233, 285, 68, 287, 68], [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 7, 11, 15, 22, 26, 30, 15, 37, 41, 44, 47, 50, 54, 11, 15, 19, 11, 15, 22, 26, 30, 61, 37, 30, 68, 72, 30, 78, 47, 84, 26, 30, 91, 37, 96, 99, 102, 105, 109, 112, 115, 117, 109, 122, 124, 128, 130, 54, 11, 15, 130, 132, 72, 30, 137, 141, 122, 147, 132, 150, 30, 68, 154, 109, 68, 157, 109, 162, 164, 30, 166, 168, 99, 102, 173, 175, 176, 177, 124, 128, 147, 132, 30, 72, 168, 184, 115, 189, 132, 96, 99, 37, 166, 195, 96, 99, 201, 150, 105, 109, 205, 164, 109, 154, 109, 157, 109, 211, 112, 213, 109, 154, 72, 109, 195, 208, 215, 124, 208, 130, 150, 166, 224, 26, 124, 157, 30, 226, 217, 166, 115, 213, 150, 30, 124, 208, 150, 195, 208, 176, 177, 124, 72, 224, 208, 233, 217, 68, 154, 195, 214, 195, 208, 109, 109, 236, 117, 195, 208, 214, 195, 201, 99, 173, 166, 168, 177, 68, 246, 213, 215, 68, 251, 173, 147, 150, 254, 166, 195, 99, 175, 208, 30, 215, 122, 164, 166, 251, 173, 154, 195, 78, 258, 166, 168, 154, 147, 150, 260, 141, 226, 217, 154, 214, 254, 184, 263, 154, 195, 154, 109, 208, 208, 269, 84, 177, 246, 150, 154, 166, 215, 195, 166, 150, 208, 150, 208, 215, 195, 215, 213, 195, 208, 213, 150, 195, 166, 254, 109, 68, 224, 233, 68, 109, 236, 201, 226, 150, 213, 166, 208, 277, 117, 278, 213, 233, 236, 215, 279, 195, 208, 224, 201, 117, 280, 254, 195, 208, 109, 109, 226, 213, 213, 215, 215, 277, 280, 195, 208, 236, 233, 195, 208], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 8, 12, 16, 23, 27, 31, 34, 38, 42, 12, 48, 51, 55, 12, 16, 20, 12, 16, 23, 56, 58, 62, 51, 65, 69, 73, 76, 79, 69, 85, 42, 89, 92, 95, 42, 100, 48, 106, 31, 113, 48, 118, 68, 48, 125, 48, 51, 55, 12, 16, 62, 51, 133, 135, 138, 56, 144, 62, 148, 151, 48, 144, 154, 154, 155, 69, 118, 154, 69, 48, 161, 79, 171, 69, 174, 69, 69, 178, 180, 69, 85, 148, 138, 182, 92, 95, 155, 135, 42, 92, 95, 148, 193, 76, 198, 200, 118, 48, 202, 58, 62, 206, 207, 69, 209, 210, 89, 92, 200, 135, 178, 216, 69, 174, 68, 68, 138, 202, 65, 219, 222, 48, 118, 148, 56, 138, 118, 154, 69, 155, 138, 228, 144, 206, 106, 229, 174, 144, 154, 144, 138, 202, 48, 144, 138, 154, 144, 68, 154, 154, 69, 228, 133, 152, 165, 154, 69, 182, 240, 155, 135, 155, 200, 135, 243, 198, 210, 244, 155, 165, 152, 249, 144, 206, 219, 252, 154, 178, 255, 113, 155, 155, 210, 240, 135, 135, 65, 151, 48, 155, 209, 92, 155, 210, 92, 244, 62, 206, 138, 202, 68, 151, 144, 161, 68, 200, 135, 265, 165, 266, 73, 152, 207, 144, 62, 48, 161, 76, 249, 138, 69, 271, 133, 73, 265, 135, 151, 144, 266, 144, 155, 182, 133, 155, 182, 161, 274, 151, 161, 265, 135, 155, 266, 151, 144, 138, 161, 275, 69, 73, 276, 144, 135, 138, 249, 68, 68, 244, 135, 161, 151, 144, 155, 138, 155, 151, 144, 155, 151, 161, 161, 249, 69, 69, 244, 144, 155, 271, 276, 144, 155, 266, 265], [5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 9, 13, 17, 24, 28, 32, 35, 39, 28, 45, 49, 52, 9, 13, 17, 21, 13, 17, 24, 57, 59, 63, 64, 66, 70, 74, 32, 80, 82, 86, 28, 32, 93, 39, 97, 101, 103, 107, 110, 114, 66, 119, 121, 49, 126, 49, 52, 9, 13, 17, 63, 64, 134, 59, 139, 142, 145, 63, 64, 152, 66, 153, 68, 144, 70, 158, 160, 151, 134, 66, 167, 169, 101, 134, 59, 70, 82, 179, 181, 82, 86, 64, 66, 74, 169, 185, 187, 190, 97, 191, 101, 64, 194, 196, 191, 101, 160, 103, 203, 160, 63, 103, 121, 195, 110, 179, 110, 212, 114, 214, 167, 213, 134, 160, 153, 121, 158, 203, 187, 220, 223, 66, 119, 57, 142, 139, 59, 151, 134, 187, 66, 214, 152, 66, 107, 230, 231, 153, 144, 145, 139, 203, 103, 232, 187, 151, 152, 153, 154, 68, 70, 214, 187, 121, 160, 68, 238, 239, 230, 70, 214, 187, 101, 59, 194, 169, 179, 245, 247, 214, 232, 70, 152, 66, 220, 253, 144, 194, 196, 101, 70, 187, 194, 256, 190, 231, 66, 152, 66, 195, 196, 80, 247, 194, 169, 213, 63, 103, 139, 203, 261, 152, 68, 239, 121, 185, 264, 213, 214, 68, 268, 121, 121, 145, 63, 139, 270, 223, 195, 66, 238, 239, 187, 74, 230, 231, 121, 266, 153, 232, 195, 236, 273, 70, 74, 239, 66, 121, 268, 245, 119, 247, 153, 144, 153, 187, 270, 253, 195, 167, 230, 232, 119, 66, 70, 261, 153, 256, 264, 236, 144, 266, 273, 158, 247, 144, 68, 273, 121, 167, 282, 195, 70, 158, 284, 266, 286, 236, 288, 68, 286, 68, 288]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288])
```

```
Automaton("det",266,4,[[1, 127, 50, 50, 115, 249, 50, 8, 257, 10, 151, 12, 13, 14, 81, 78, 34, 106, 137, 107, 21, 22, 82, 89, 71, 43, 43, 62, 63, 63, 44, 10, 179, 171, 214, 265, 206, 38, 137, 152, 21, 151, 71, 22, 41, 41, 47, 13, 49, 50, 50, 210, 50, 210, 116, 90, 64, 49, 207, 207, 207, 62, 232, 64, 64, 89, 151, 236, 236, 70, 71, 236, 116, 260, 128, 75, 13, 38, 77, 133, 14, 82, 13, 13, 77, 235, 64, 64, 231, 206, 138, 91, 91, 206, 90, 264, 137, 169, 10, 10, 41, 71, 232, 228, 232, 21, 21, 107, 106, 110, 111, 266, 256, 114, 114, 116, 251, 251, 116, 114, 114, 111, 266, 260, 122, 182, 127, 128, 129, 213, 132, 132, 129, 49, 49, 138, 138, 138, 249, 71, 43, 43, 210, 235, 183, 214, 132, 265, 206, 138, 232, 64, 64, 153, 153, 64, 152, 152, 82, 236, 236, 82, 116, 116, 64, 207, 266, 64, 231, 169, 171, 250, 227, 70, 175, 175, 176, 10, 47, 178, 178, 110, 111, 266, 260, 122, 266, 127, 213, 49, 49, 152, 257, 153, 257, 90, 90, 183, 250, 264, 62, 228, 229, 82, 82, 206, 64, 266, 249, 249, 249, 242, 213, 214, 64, 116, 114, 114, 50, 50, 236, 236, 261, 115, 152, 251, 8, 228, 229, 229, 231, 232, 237, 235, 235, 236, 237, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 242, 242, 242, 115, 251, 249, 250, 116, 116, 116, 207, 64, 265, 266, 257, 256, 266, 264, 261, 260, 264, 265, 266], [1, 125, 1, 114, 114, 121, 115, 3, 23, 19, 13, 15, 230, 28, 201, 202, 16, 84, 123, 103, 105, 208, 114, 84, 172, 199, 199, 119, 83, 83, 123, 170, 16, 31, 27, 26, 25, 104, 102, 23, 28, 13, 120, 208, 48, 103, 19, 230, 239, 1, 114, 218, 115, 219, 82, 140, 23, 208, 204, 216, 216, 119, 174, 119, 119, 84, 13, 115, 115, 50, 120, 50, 82, 204, 262, 79, 230, 104, 203, 85, 28, 114, 230, 230, 203, 3, 23, 119, 96, 96, 96, 123, 102, 140, 208, 3, 200, 200, 98, 97, 103, 120, 119, 120, 119, 28, 105, 103, 105, 54, 3, 23, 141, 1, 250, 50, 82, 114, 50, 1, 250, 3, 3, 219, 219, 125, 54, 263, 124, 124, 27, 124, 223, 208, 239, 25, 208, 208, 120, 120, 217, 217, 217, 120, 120, 142, 142, 141, 140, 140, 174, 174, 174, 204, 216, 23, 119, 23, 250, 114, 114, 250, 162, 162, 159, 205, 159, 159, 208, 123, 170, 1, 219, 50, 208, 208, 123, 177, 177, 19, 170, 173, 172, 172, 199, 199, 23, 186, 185, 184, 184, 23, 120, 216, 23, 140, 208, 120, 1, 3, 119, 120, 114, 114, 250, 239, 119, 3, 121, 3, 120, 219, 212, 212, 23, 50, 1, 250, 1, 114, 50, 114, 219, 114, 23, 114, 3, 120, 114, 114, 208, 119, 125, 121, 3, 50, 54, 120, 3, 120, 121, 3, 120, 218, 219, 217, 114, 114, 3, 1, 250, 250, 250, 253, 252, 173, 172, 120, 125, 3, 3, 219, 219, 3, 54, 3], [1, 1, 249, 249, 6, 1, 1, 247, 7, 130, 167, 17, 11, 66, 33, 33, 131, 136, 10, 32, 150, 9, 112, 36, 149, 112, 149, 56, 167, 37, 181, 130, 35, 147, 139, 51, 139, 11, 10, 234, 147, 37, 148, 113, 136, 136, 146, 24, 249, 1, 1, 249, 249, 249, 139, 6, 238, 127, 134, 238, 134, 9, 148, 238, 134, 167, 36, 50, 249, 247, 73, 249, 51, 139, 112, 167, 76, 76, 11, 167, 80, 73, 67, 66, 66, 135, 58, 58, 112, 139, 233, 100, 100, 2, 6, 95, 10, 32, 130, 130, 99, 94, 94, 56, 149, 150, 147, 150, 136, 51, 51, 51, 7, 51, 51, 51, 7, 6, 139, 139, 139, 2, 58, 134, 139, 7, 1, 112, 112, 249, 238, 238, 112, 249, 127, 238, 233, 238, 1, 149, 112, 149, 249, 135, 7, 139, 238, 51, 139, 238, 112, 238, 233, 234, 234, 134, 234, 190, 112, 50, 249, 73, 139, 51, 238, 134, 51, 134, 148, 32, 147, 145, 145, 145, 258, 259, 180, 130, 146, 189, 189, 51, 51, 134, 134, 139, 2, 1, 249, 127, 249, 191, 191, 191, 188, 188, 188, 188, 198, 197, 196, 196, 195, 187, 187, 139, 233, 134, 127, 127, 127, 49, 249, 139, 243, 211, 211, 211, 210, 210, 210, 210, 95, 209, 241, 209, 126, 117, 117, 9, 112, 112, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 127, 127, 127, 249, 249, 249, 7, 7, 1, 247, 51, 139, 211, 134, 134, 51, 51, 7, 7, 2, 126, 145, 139, 247, 51, 51], [1, 51, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 50, 73, 61, 11, 12, 40, 109, 101, 93, 45, 18, 19, 20, 21, 64, 161, 29, 193, 118, 193, 65, 11, 42, 19, 59, 30, 46, 163, 164, 163, 40, 39, 57, 46, 42, 246, 60, 18, 21, 61, 158, 72, 50, 51, 53, 53, 3, 55, 55, 57, 246, 156, 64, 65, 64, 155, 64, 65, 11, 29, 68, 69, 236, 160, 72, 73, 55, 157, 11, 154, 154, 40, 11, 46, 160, 225, 192, 192, 86, 87, 88, 157, 118, 155, 19, 39, 74, 161, 239, 92, 92, 166, 254, 20, 144, 88, 240, 65, 109, 108, 21, 21, 50, 50, 73, 73, 50, 247, 236, 73, 161, 72, 3, 5, 54, 86, 239, 3, 51, 50, 64, 64, 161, 165, 64, 157, 161, 245, 165, 60, 64, 51, 240, 161, 240, 4, 144, 51, 55, 57, 73, 55, 57, 157, 157, 155, 57, 64, 156, 64, 87, 118, 160, 161, 248, 163, 164, 165, 168, 164, 168, 60, 19, 108, 3, 3, 72, 64, 60, 19, 194, 194, 61, 59, 247, 247, 193, 193, 5, 74, 7, 69, 244, 69, 156, 240, 65, 74, 74, 246, 143, 219, 86, 88, 144, 222, 222, 226, 72, 60, 239, 52, 54, 143, 239, 72, 72, 215, 221, 219, 224, 219, 220, 221, 222, 239, 220, 215, 222, 54, 160, 160, 161, 64, 64, 160, 68, 236, 236, 236, 160, 239, 240, 244, 245, 246, 69, 72, 161, 51, 160, 50, 50, 248, 118, 226, 255, 255, 248, 248, 160, 160, 245, 245, 72, 72, 236, 236, 236]],[12],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266])
```

4.

```
Automaton("det",9,4,[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2], [1, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2], [1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],[4],[2, 6])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 78, 79, 81, 84, 85, 86, 90, 93, 94, 95, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 75, 76, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 92, 93, 95, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38, 40, 41, 45, 47, 49, 50, 53, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 39, 40, 42, 43, 46, 47, 51, 54, 55, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 67, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 82, 84, 85, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[39],[1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 31, 33, 35, 37, 41, 42, 43, 44, 49, 50, 52, 53, 57, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 69, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100])
```

5.

A [pair of equivalent DFAs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GNTvfXCCt7/)

## Non-equivalent DFAs

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 56, 57, 60, 62, 64, 65, 69, 70, 73, 74, 76, 80, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 47, 49, 52, 53, 54, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 69, 71, 72, 75, 76, 78, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 46, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 80, 83, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36, 37, 40, 42, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 56, 58, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[52],[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 60, 61, 62, 66, 67, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 89, 90, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 48, 49, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 69, 71, 72, 73, 76, 78, 79, 80, 83, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 95, 96, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 56, 57, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 96, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 45, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 56, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 82, 84, 85, 86, 89, 90, 93, 94, 97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 28, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 70, 74, 76, 83, 84, 86, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[17],[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 22, 23, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 35, 36, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 79, 83, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 35, 36, 37, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 72, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 5, 8, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 56, 59, 61, 63, 64, 65, 68, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 85, 86, 87, 88, 92, 93, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 62, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 84, 86, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[46],[1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 86, 88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 62, 63, 67, 68, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 85, 87, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 92, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 70, 71, 75, 76, 77, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 82, 83, 86, 87, 88, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[45],[2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 37, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 71, 72, 76, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 91, 92, 94, 95, 99, 100])
```

## Score

This question is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [restricted-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-time).  Your code must be able to run all the test cases in less than a minute on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

### Island Rose Breeder

Island Roses have an extremely simple genetic code, with just 4 genes: R, Y, W, and B, each with two alleles. This means their entire genome can be represented by four 2-bit gene pairs of the form: `00-00-00-00` (`01` and `10` are equivalent)

Island Roses can be bred together. When two roses are bred, each parent flower donates one allele for each gene. This can be represented by Mendelian genetics via a Punnett square:

[image]

For instance, a `01-00-11-11` flower that is bred with a `01-00-11-11` flower will result in either:

- a `00-00-11-11` flower (25% chance)
- a `01-00-11-11` flower (50% chance)
- a `11-00-11-11` flower (25% chance)

Based on their genes, Island Roses can display one of 8 phenotypes -- colors.

A list of the genotypes and their corresponding phenotypes can be [found here](https://pastebin.com/VuVrd8N2).

### Challenge

Given a starting stock of Roses, determine how many generations (and which Roses to use) it would take to breed a particular phenotype.

Because genetic testing is expensive, you can only identify the results of breeding by observing the phenotype of the offspring. For example, Breeding two `11-00-00-01` (Red) roses gives three distinct phenotypes, so any Black rose that results *must* have genotype of `11-00-00-11`.

In the case of ambiguous phenotypes, subsequent generations of breeding can be done to disambiguate the specific phenotypes.

**Example**
Input Roses:

- `11-00-00-01`
- `00-00-01-00`
- `00-11-00-00`

Target Phenotype:

- `11-11-11-00`

Comment: Could you add some examples of what output should look like? Some test cases showing `input -> output` would also be helpful. Finally, make sure to mention the winning criteria (eg. if it's Code Golf, you should explicitly mention that)

Answer (score 1):

## Vampire Bats [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)

TwilightSparkle needs help controlling COVID-19 in Equestria.

The bats are spreading the virus in the APL orchard. The orchard is an N×M rectangle of APL trees and the bats are on some of the trees.

The "Asdfjklio" spell can be casted to travel through a specified path starts on a bat and ends on a bat and destroy every bats it reaches. Asdfjklio can only move horizontally or vertically.

Your task is to output how many paths are there to destroy all of the bats.

> **They crossed the line, it's time to fight them back!**

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

### An example

Suppose there are two bats on respective grids, where `X` stands for the bats and `.` stands for empty spaces:

```
.X
X.
```

The Asdfjklio spell can travel in any path specified, although it has to start with a bat grid and end with a bat grid.

So there are 4 possible ways to destroy all the bats:

```
>>| ^| v|<<|
^ |>>|<<|v |
```

### Sandbox

- Is this task a dupe? If so I would change it to other (less interesting) candidates.
- Input format?

Comment: 0 paths, because there are no bats in Equestria!

Comment: @petStorm Okay. How do I clarify the question?

Comment: So it is about counting all paths that starts and ends with a bat, and goes through every single bat on the grid, not visiting any grid cell twice, right? Do we count all paths regardless of the path lengths (e.g. if the grid is `XX\n..`, the U-shaped path does count too)? What if there is only one bat or no bats?

Comment: If you have problem describing the I/O format, look for existing challenges on main that have similar kind of I/O. As it involves a 2D grid, checking out [tag:grid] will help.

Comment: @Bubbler Yep, regardless of the path length.

Comment: I wonder whether is this NP-hard (and, if so, what related problems exist).

Answer (score 1):

## Linear recurrences [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [maths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths)

This is the fourth post for the [second RGS's Golfing Showdown](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18874/75323).

## Rationale

Feel free to skip this, as I'm just sharing the train of thought that led me to creating this challenge.

The Fibonacci sequence we all know and love (?) is the sequence that whose first terms are

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040
```

and starting from `1 1`, each following number is obtained from the sum of the previous two. An interesting thing about the Fibonacci sequence is that it can be used to [calculate the growth of a population of rabbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#History) (see 4th, 5th, ... chapters of the linked section). Then I thought, what if I use it to calculate the number of people infected by COVID?

I tried reasoning to try and find sensible weights for a possible mock linear recursion to model the number of infected people, but I failed to do so. I need you to help *me* test my models.

## Task

Code a function that takes a set of initial values and a set of weights (with the same length as the set of initial values) and then allows one to generate the sequence specified by the initial values and weights. Formally, if the \$k\$ initial values are \$T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_k\$ and the weights are \$w_1, w_2, ..., w_k\$ then the \$n\$th term of your sequence is given by \$T_n\$ if \$n \leq k\$, otherwise it is defined recursively by

$$T_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^k T_{n-i}w_{k-i+1} = T_{n-1}w_{k-1} + T_{n-2}w_{k-2} + \cdots + T_{n-k}w_{1}$$

## Input

You must take two lists of numbers as input for the initial values and weights. Any sensible format is allowed. One or both lists can be reversed.

Additionally, you can

- take no extra input and generate the sequence infinitely
- take an extra integer `n` and generate the first `n` terms
- take an extra integer `n` and generate the nth term (0- or 1- indexed)

## Output

See input section above.

## Test cases

Each 3 lines give the initial values, the weights, and then the first 10 terms of each sequence. [Reference APL program](https://tio.run/##ZVGxTsMwEN3zFW/DFmnVpIihiD9AQuIHKitc2kjBKY7TClVdAJVSFAQDgoWFqTvqwgh/4h8JjlsgEvLJ5/fe3fNZFqO0dXoh0mxQVf2jRJJQJxQVKk8y2YeZP2DqwZSvOB6REjpTPaQUawhF0ENCIhOdiBRjkRaU@1DJYPinTqiG@QEiRUJTjriQkbbWUKQLJRM5gNRDaFJnyGLXk9N5QTKi@toPN4HNNjwEh6Zc92CWVw4yi1oBh1ncmHIF1jK3b5tSbuaPNvm2wMZu@@u5bph5nh1B57UlM8tL5gec@SHnfgN2OYfPfBbAogAhZ2G9BdjnZvHSnrqZyvVsU@C0LvZ@PWp62wlr1aDDH8GtjtU8bzrGZPvCNczdNWKHxvj/ExOnm/snWzBunJt8/LmyTu9Bp8Ht7Mws695dVd8).

Bonus imaginary internet points if your solution handles floating point initial values/weights.

```
1
2
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512

1
3
1 3 9 27 81 243 729 2187 6561 19683

1 1
1 1
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

1 1
2 2
1 1 4 10 28 76 208 568 1552 4240

1 1
3 4
1 1 7 31 145 673 3127 14527 67489 313537


1 2
1 1
1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89

1 2
2 2
1 2 6 16 44 120 328 896 2448 6688

1 2
3 4
1 2 11 50 233 1082 5027 23354 108497 504050

2 2
1 1
2 2 4 6 10 16 26 42 68 110

2 2
2 2
2 2 8 20 56 152 416 1136 3104 8480

2 2
3 4
2 2 14 62 290 1346 6254 29054 134978 627074

1 6
1 1
1 6 7 13 20 33 53 86 139 225

1 6
2 2
1 6 14 40 108 296 808 2208 6032 16480

1 6
3 4
1 6 27 126 585 2718 12627 58662 272529 1266102

1 1 1
1 2 3
1 1 1 6 21 76 276 1001 3631 13171

1 2 1 1
1 1 1 10
1 2 1 1 14 144 1456 14719 148804 1504359
```

Comment: Mathematica has `LinearRecurrence` (of course).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate that doesn't bother me; Mathematica's builtins tend to be long. I expect submissions shorter than that :)

Comment: How is this a reference program? I can't read it.

Comment: I don't see why this is -2.

Answer (score 1):

### Which anagram is the user trying to guess?

#### Input

1. A list (in any form) of target words
2. A guess word

You can take these in any form (eg, an array in which the first element is the guess word).

#### Output

- If the letters of the guess word occur (in any order) in exactly one of the target words, output that target word.
- Otherwise do something other than output letters. (Outputting nothing, or a number is fine. Throwing an error is fine. Infinite looping is not fine. :))

#### Assumptions

- The members of the list, and the guess word, are each strings of 1-15 lowercase letters.
- Members of the list might be anagrams of each other. (In this case, no guess word will ever succeed.)

#### Examples

- list: fish, dog, cat, horse, porcupine:
- guess: re -> (fail)
- guess: so -> horse
- guess: god -> dog
- guess: kitten -> (fail)

#### Scoring and rules.

Code golf. Standard rules, no standard loopholes etc.

Comment: "Don't assume that no two members of the list are anagrams of each other"
The double negative is hard to read at first glance, consider changing it to "Members of the list may be anagrams of each other"

Comment: Related: [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/determine-whether-strings-are-anagrams)

Comment: @mathjunkie Thanks, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Premise

I've crafted this zero-player game in an attempt to create a problem simple to explain but that would require an intricate implementation.
Sadly in the making of it, I realized that annoying conditions are required for safety (avoid to get stuck in loops) and non-ambiguity.

*Ask me justifications for any rule that seems too arbitrary. Unfortunately it turned out to be 50% design and 50% precautions.*

## Turning Tiles game

The field of this game is a [square toroidal grid](https://www.google.com/search?q=toroidal+grid&sxsrf=ALeKk00zPr0KXqKlqJnTbEU7iskw6hvZ8Q:1588277096042&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis5vSg-ZDpAhWCDOwKHWwhAi8Q_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1920&bih=979#imgrc=DNpOW7cXm2Nv9M) (like that of Snake or Pacman) populated by `dots`. Each grid unit is one of the following:

- `tile` (there are \$4\$ type of tile, indicating directions e.g.: `^` `>` `v` `<` or `1` `2` `3` `4`)
- `wormhole`

The dot behaviour is very simple: it moves following the direction indicated by the tiles it walks on, and to wreak havoc after each step it rotates the left tile *in a copycat fashion*.
When two dots collide they will remain together forever and can be considered as one.
So the dots will either converge into one (wormholes facilitate this scenario) or remain stuck in a loop.

### Detailed explanation:

One iteration of the game consists of three phases:

- Move (**M**)
- Peek (**P**)
- Edit (**E**)

Phases are performed individually by each dot: next phase will begin only when every dot completed current phase.

At the beginning of iteration **i** there are **n<sub>i</sub>** distinct dots.
(when n>0) if **n<sub>i</sub> < n<sub>i-1</sub>** then iteration **i** is a `downgraded iteration`.

Let `x` be a dot.

> *def* `tunnelling?`:
>   - If x is on a `tile` do nothing.
>   - If x is on a `wormhole` it will immediately exit from the *linked wormhole* keeping the direction and `tunnelling?` is called.
>
> *def* `handle_overwrite_error`:
>   - If multiple overwrite errors occurred in current iteration, x won't overwrite its starting tile.
>   - Else a `wormhole` will open in place of x's starting tile.

**begin iteration**

**M:**
The tile x is on becomes its `starting tile`.
x moves one unit in the direction indicated by its `starting tile` and `tunnelling?` is called.
The tile x is on becomes its `landing tile`.
**___**

**P:**
x peeks at the `landing tile` of its *closest* dot(s) and plans its editing.
If the overwiting direction can't be uniquely determined *(*)* an `overwrite error` will rise for x.
**___**

**E:**
If x raised an `overwrite error`, `handle_overwrite_error` is now called.
Else x overwrites its `starting tile` with the direction decided in **P**.
**___**

If a wormhole appeared under someone's feet, that dot disappear (exiting direction couldn't be decided).
(This rule guaratees that `tunnelling?` will always terminate.)

**end iteration**

**Wormholes chain:** since one single wormhole is allowed to open in each iteration, wormholes inherit their linkage order by the chronological order they popped-up. Last wormhole close the chain.

**Metric:** unsurprisingly [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) applyied on a toroidal grid...

- But here can enter the picture a devilish modification. What if the wormholes play a role in the metric? So that let's say x and y are 2 unit apart, with a wormhole in between they would be 4 unit apart instead. Also to find the closest dot would be totally trickier, cause the paths through any nearby wormhole have to be tried.

*(*)*: For the overwriting direction not to be decidible the presence of multiple dots sharing the propriety *"x doesn't have any dot closer than me"* is necessary but not sufficient. Also their landing tiles have not to be the same.

## What can be asked? (feedback)

Is this an interesting game?

Probably I've exaggerated it in the explanation but I cared to be as clear as possible and many requirements are conceivable to make it work.
Of course if that's too much I'd give up wormhole...

Rules in [Shortest Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/shortest-game-of-life) inspires me

Of course the **input** would be the starting configuration, should wormholes be prohibited in input?

If simulation is not visually shown there would be an `ITERATION_CAP`
Fixed or passed in input as well?

Regarding **output**, the quirk of this game are the downgraded iterations. I thought that the sequence (or sum) of their indices can be returned along with last number of distinct dots...

This will be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins.
[Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

### Modular distance [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

You are given 3 non-negative integers: the domain `d`, the beginning index `b`, and the ending index `e`.

### What is a modular distance?

Assume `d=5` here. First, generate a range from `0` to `5-1`:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

We start from the beginning index. Assuming that is `3`:

```
0 1 2 3 4
      ^
```

We continually go right, circling every number we've passed, until we met the ending index `e`.

```
0 1 2 O O
        ^
```

If the pointer is at the right end, it wraps around to the left.

Assuming `e=0`:

```
O 1 2 O O
^
```

We filter out every item we've circled:

```
0 3 4
```

Then, find how many items there are in this list:

```
3
```

Subtract it by 1 and it's our result:

```
2
```

### Specification

- You can always assume that `b<d` and `e<d`.

### Test cases

```
6 2 5 -> 3
5 3 0 -> 2
```

Comment: Do you mean to say "we filter out every item we _haven't_ circled"?

Comment: Is the modular distance just \$ (e - b) \bmod d\$ ?

Answer (score 1):

## Parse vietnamese infinite decimal notation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

I wanted to express infinite decimals in text, but overlines are hard.

You need to take a decimal in vietnamese notation, and output the first 10 or more digits of the normal variant.

### The notation

The way it works is that you have `0.ab(cd)` and it means `0.abcdcdcd...`. Of course, you can have any amount of digits in each spot, even zero. You can also omit the infinite part to represent finite decimals.

### Notes

It's allowed to not accept `0.2` or `0.2()` as input, and it's also allowed to output `0.2000000000` if you do accept them as input.

Comment: Can we output the variant infinitely, instead of outputting the first 10 digits?

Comment: An existing keyboard-friendly notation is `0.ab(cd)` ([Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Notation)).

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Sure. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So is the challenge just to split at the `(` and then append the first part to the stuff in the brackets repeated 10 times?

Comment: Is this a good time to post the question?

Answer (score 1):

## Arithmetic Square [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

*Note: Credit goes to [CCC 2019 S3](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2019/stage%201/seniorEF.pdf) for the problem*

You are given a \$ 3 \times 3 \$ grid which contains integers. Some of the \$ 9 \$ elements in the grid already have a value, and some of them remain *unknown*.

Your task is to fill in values for the *unknown* elements such that for each row, when read left-to-right, produces an arithmetic sequence, and that for each column, when read top-to-bottom, is also an arithmetic sequence.

Recall that an arithmetic sequence of length \$ 3 \$ is a sequence of integers in the form

$$ a, a + d, a + 2d $$

for integer values of \$ a \$ and \$ d \$. Note that \$ d \$ may be any integer, including zero and negatives.

### Input Specification

- You may input the \$ 3 \times 3 \$ grid in any sensible format
- The *unknown* values may be represented by any character, so long that it is not a number (i.e. \$ 0-9 \$)

### Output Specification

- The output must be in the same format as the input, with the exception of *unknown* values becoming integers
- All rows and columns must form arithmetic sequences
- There is guaranteed to be at least one solution, and you may output any of them

### Test Cases

```
(This is the only solution)
 8  9 10       8  9 10
16  X 20  ->  16 18 20
24  X 30      24 27 30

(This is one of many solutions)
14  X  X      14 20 26
 X  X 18  ->  18 18 18
 X 16  X      22 16 10

(This is the only solution)
 X -1 -2       0 -1 -2
 5  X  3  ->   5  4  3
 X  X  X      10  9  8

(This is one of many solutions)
 X  X  X       0  0  0
 X  X  X  ->   0  0  0
 X  X  X       0  0  0
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Answer (score 1):

### Posted

[Tile the plane with squashed hexagons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204726/tile-the-plane-with-squashed-hexagons)

Answer (score 1):

### Generate a "Poem" [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given a strictly positive integer, `N`, produce an output satisfying the following:

- Produce an array of length N.
- Every string (i.e. "word") in the array is of length N.
- Every letter in the word is unique.
- Every first letter of the words are unique between each other.
- The remaining items of each word are equal to each other.

### Example output

For an input of e.g. `3`:

```
cba
dba
eba
```

### Specification

- Trailing whitespace is totally allowed.
- The "letters" don't have to be from the lowercase alphabet, as long as they aren't whitespace.
- The maximum `N` you need to support is 13, since there are 26 letters in the lowercase alphabet.
- The separator of your array can be anything, as long as you will never involve that character for every possible input from 1 to 13. You can also just output a literal array.

Comment: is there a maximum `N` we need to support?

Comment: Yes, the maximum `N` here is 13.

Answer (score 1):

### Compress a grandmaster chess position [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

**Background**

Compress a position from a grandmaster chess game to as few bits as possible on average. A strong submission will probably use that these positions come from real games by top players, and so will make chess sense and strategic sense, rather than just being random legal chess positions. As illustration, [a study](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03213216.pdf) found that grandmasters do well at memorizing positions from real games using "chunking" but with only perform at novice level memorizing random boards.

The is related to but different from [Smallest chess board compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19397/20260), which scores on the worst-case scenario, and [Smallest chess game compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132725/20260), which compresses full games. (*Sandbox*: Let me know if this is too similar)

**Task**

You must write a compressor, which maps a chess position onto a sequence of bits, and a decompressor that returns its to the original position. You can vary the length of the bit sequence by position, and this will likely be important to getting a good score.

The position to compress will just be a the placement of pieces on the chess board. You do not to encode whose move it is, castling rights, or en-passant. It will be given in [FEN string format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) with only the piece placement part, for example:

```
2krn2r/pppb4/4pq2/3pN2p/5P2/2PBP3/PP4P1/R2QK2R
```

[image: The chess position for this FEN]

Each letter corresponds to a piece (pawn="P", knight="N", bishop="B", rook="R", queen="Q", and king="K"). White's pieces use uppercase letters and Black's are lowercase. Slashes separate the descriptions of each of the rows from top to bottom, that is the 8 files doing from 8 (where black's pieces start) to down to 1. Numbers are used for blocks of that many empty spaces that are horizontally adjacent.

**Scoring**

You will be scored on the average length of your compressed bit sequence on 10,000 random game positions. They will chosen at random from games played by grandmasters, restricted to move 5 or later. [Will work out more details when generating this data.]

This Pastebin (TODO) contains 10,000 FEN strings to use as a training set that you can use to get a preliminary score. The final score will be based on a separate secret test set of 10,000 FEN strings.

Your code must correctly decode every game in the position. Be sure that it can handle all positions, such as ones with weird underpromotions, which might appear in the test set but not the training set. (*Sandbox:* How to handle submissions that break this? A default penalty score for games failed? Ask to resubmit?)

Your compression and decompression must complete within 5 minutes on all the games. (*Sandbox:* Allow to compress all games at once? Do one game at a time but store state to allow "learning"? Include a memory limit?)

The length of your code is immaterial to this challenge.

Comment: How long (in number of positions) would a naive program that hardcodes all of the (recorded) existing grandmasters games be? (if that's not large enough, it would make the challenge trivial)

Comment: @user202729 That's a good question, I definitely don't want code to be use that the test set comes from an actual database, so I'd either needed to make that non-viable or ban it.

Comment: Does the time requirement have to be as strict as 30 games per second? (a certain question of the part also mentions "every game in the position", I assume that's a mistake) (I have no idea how to prevent storing a database of grandmaster games though)

Comment: @myp I think that this requirement means that it can compress each game in 5 minutes.

Comment: @user202729 I had meant total for all the games, but I'll probably loosen it.

Answer (score 1):

### Permutation primes [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations) [prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime)

A *permutation prime* is a prime such that at least one of its uniquified permutations (*not* equal to itself) of its digits is a prime.

Given a number, check if this number is a permutation prime.

### Reference program

[Here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6OTDM09NKqhNN3zUsOv/f0MjQwA) is a reference program I made.

Answer (score 1):

Posted: [Stepping Through Time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205086/stepping-through-time)

Answer (score 1):

## The golfing skills are strong with this one [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Task

Consider the base string `s = "The golfing skills are strong with this one"`, an adaptation of the quote "The force is strong with this one" by Darth Vader, an infamous character of the Star Wars saga (sandbox, am I correct?).

You have to output the string `s` with as many characters as there are bytes in your source code. If your code is longer than `s`, extend `s` by concatenating it repeatedly as many times as needed.

Your program must be non-empty.

## Input

You may or may not take the string `s` as input for your program. (Sandbox, maybe it is more interesting to *not* allow the string as input?)

## Output

A string as specified in the **Task**.

Comment: Many languages, 0 bytes. PHP and /// polyglot, 1 byte: `T`. If the code is too long, is the string really intended to be `The golfing skills are strong with this oneThe golfing skills are strong with this oneThe golfing skills are strong with this one`?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate do you see a problem with the string being like that? What would you suggest? Also, probably should not allow the string to be used as input and require a non-empty program

Comment: That is perfectly acceptable, it's just that the transitions aren't very smooth (`oneThe`). If you can take the string as input, solutions won't have to depend on this specific string, so it would probably be a bad idea. (I mean, `a[:5]` isn't a very interesting answer)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I failed to understand what variation you think is a bad idea. Do you think it is a bad idea to accept it as input or a bad idea to not accept it as input?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to accept it as input.

Answer (score 1):

## Halting problem for simplified Brainfuck [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given a simplified Brainfuck program, you must determine whether it halts. Your program  must always halt in finite time on valid inputs.

Simplified Brainfuck is a language that operates on a zero-initialized tape that is infinite in both directions. All cells contain integers from 0 to 255, and operations are performed modulo 256.
There are the following instructions:

```
+ increment the current cell
- decrement the current cell
< move 1 cell to the left along the tape
> move 1 cell to the right along the tape
[ if the current cell is zero, skip past the next ]
] go to the previous [
```

Loops (`[]`) can't be nested.

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: Do you mean "Given a simplified Brainfuck program _and an input of such program_"?

Comment: @DomenicoModica No, this language has no IO. Do you think I should mention that explicitly?

Comment: Oh, I don't know, I was too hasty ahahah... Anyway If the tape was finite surely it would be solvable

Comment: I think it is indeed solvable with doubly infinite tape, since the region that the pointer touches within an iteration of a loop is limited (which means we have finite number of states in that region). It's pretty hard to describe the algorithm though.

Comment: That is what I had in mind.  Handling two loops in different directions is also non-trivial.

Comment: I don't think handling multiple loops is that non-trivial. Consider first loop first, the answer is false if it is infinite loop, otherwise run it to the end and run all commands before the second loop. Then consider the second loop just like the first, etc.

Comment: Actually I think the challenge is not very interesting as[code-golf], because it's necessary to simulate the algorithm anyway and it can be proven (I think) that the number of steps the program takes (if it halts) is no more than \$2^{2^{2^{2^n}}}\$ (where n is the program length), so it will be no longer than an interpreter but takes impractically long to run.

Comment: @user202729 Is there proof of an upper bound of time? I feel it's unsolvable

Comment: @l4m2 This is solvable because loops can't be nested. The body of each loops moves by a constant number of steps X, and if the program doesn't halt than it'll either repeat the same state twice (if X==0) or crosses the bound of the written tape part (because there's only a fixed number of written cells and then repeat states (there's only a finite number of cells touched by the loop body)

Answer (score 1):

## Cheat activated

#### Background

The game [Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas) went down to history also thanks to its wide selection of cheats. They're almost 90 and anyone who has ever touched this game, no doubt he tried them all!
One cheat is activated (on PC) typing in-game a secret keyword, and then boom, a jet pops out of thin air or perhaps all pedestrians look like Elvis Presley or some other rowdy effect...

*They always come with this confirmation message:*

[image]

Rockstar [choosed to store them hashed](https://gtagmodding.com/sanandreas/cheats/), so due to collision, in addition to the intended ones there are many other strings that trigger every cheat.

Therefore I propose to solve this [downside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrXhYgVmKLQ)!

### Task

Write a full program that prints `CHEAT ACTIVATED` if and only if the last part of a string is a `cheat code`.

### Cheat codes

```
THUGSARMOURY
PROFESSIONALSKIT
NUTTERSTOYS
INEEDSOMEHELP
TURNUPTHEHEAT
TURNDOWNTHEHEAT
PLEASANTLYWARM
TOODAMNHOT
DULLDULLDAY
STAYINANDWATCHTV
CANTSEEWHEREIMGOING
TIMEJUSTFLIESBY
SPEEDITUP
SLOWITDOWN
ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD
STOPPICKINGONME
SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS
TIMETOKICKASS
OLDSPEEDDEMON
DOUGHNUTHANDICAP
NOTFORPUBLICROADS
JUSTTRYANDSTOPME
WHERESTHEFUNERAL
CELEBRITYSTATUS
TRUEGRIME
ALLCARSGOBOOM
WHEELSONLYPLEASE
STICKLIKEGLUE
GOODBYECRUELWORLD
DONTTRYANDSTOPME
ALLDRIVERSARECRIMINALS
PINKISTHENEWCOOL
SOLONGASITSBLACK
FLYINGFISH
WHOATEALLTHEPIES
BUFFMEUP
LEANANDMEAN
BLUESUEDESHOES
ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE
LIFESABEACH
ONLYHOMIESALLOWED
BETTERSTAYINDOORS
NINJATOWN
LOVECONQUERSALL
EVERYONEISPOOR
EVERYONEISRICH
CHITTYCHITTYBANGBANG
CJPHONEHOME
JUMPJET
IWANTTOHOVER
TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE
SPEEDFREAK
BUBBLECARS
NIGHTPROWLER
DONTBRINGONTHENIGHT
SCOTTISHSUMMER
SANDINMYEARS
KANGAROO
NOONECANHURTME
MANFROMATLANTIS
LETSGOBASEJUMPING
ROCKETMAN
IDOASIPLEASE
BRINGITON
STINGLIKEABEE
IAMNEVERHUNGRY
STATEOFEMERGENCY
CRAZYTOWN
TAKEACHILLPILL
FULLCLIP
IWANNADRIVEBY
GHOSTTOWN
HICKSVILLE
WANNABEINMYGANG
NOONECANSTOPUS
ROCKETMAYHEM
WORSHIPME
HELLOLADIES
ICANGOALLNIGHT
PROFESSIONALKILLER
NATURALTALENT
OHDUDE
FOURWHEELFUN
HITTHEROADJACK
ITSALLBULL
FLYINGTOSTUNT
MONSTERMASH
```

### Input

- A string \$s\$ over the alphabet:
  `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]`

## Output

- Print `CHEAT ACTIVATED` if there exist a `cheat code` \$c\$ such that \$c\$ is a [suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Suffix) of \$s\$
- Nothing otherwise

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: Do we have to output the specific `Cheat activated` string, or just a truthy/falsy value indicating whether or not a valid cheat code exists? (I also don't think \$i\$ is a good name for a string; is that intentional?)

Comment: @my pronoun is monicareinstate Yes, that specific string, it's a little simulation. And yes, you're right \$s\$ is the canonical name, I choose "i" for input, but never mind

Comment: I think that restricting the output to `Cheat activated` is unnecessary since it doesn't really add anything to the challenge. Consider allowing just a truthy or falsey value as output.

Comment: @math junkie I'm aware that in terms of logic it's useless. But that comes if only the "recognition part" is considered being the intended challenge. From my idea, generating `Cheat activated` it's also a part of it... I worded it badly in the task part

Comment: `18HOLES` is in the cheat codes list, yet the input states that there will be no number. Is this intended?

Comment: @dingledooper No, my mistake, I thought I had removed it in the last edit

Answer (score 1):

## Quickly calculate \$ n! \bmod p \$ [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial)

The idea is extremely simple: Given two positive integers \$ n \$ and \$ p \$, calculate the result of \$ n! \bmod p \$, where \$ p \$ is a *prime*.

### Scoring

Your score is the highest \$ p \$ you can achieve within \$ 10 \$ seconds, by running the program \$ 10 \$ separate times. More specifically, each run-through will contain two inputs \$ n \$ and \$ p \$. You are to solve \$ n! \bmod p \$, where \$ n \$ is a random number in the range \$[1, p]\$.

You must use [this](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoAgEEX3c4pZjhCiLoMOE2jlQmeYbNHpzYhWn/d4fLnbwTX0nouwNtS1Ri4AggvmKlcjA5@zZ0qRggvOAGysmEfw9nsi78wMKJrr/2DfGUh@QjG9e/cA) program to generate the \$ 10 \$ test cases. So for example, if \$ p = 13 \$, the test case would look like this:

```
n, p
9, 13
3, 13
10, 13
13, 13
7, 13
13, 13
8, 13
9, 13
6, 13
4, 13
```

### Rules

- Make sure that each test case is run *separately*, meaning you are not allowed to make use of previous test cases
- Multi-threading is disallowed
- Official times will be tested on my machine; make sure to include specifcations on how to run it

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the highest score wins!

### Sandbox

- Any loopholes that need to be addressed?
- Is there an easy, trivial solution to this?

Comment: To force independent calculation you should invoke the program 10 separate times. Although it remains possible to store data in files or similar, it would be pretty obvious.

Comment: As far as I know the best-known time complexity is asymptotically \$ \widetilde O (\sqrt p)\$, although the implementation is rather tedious and uninteresting.

Comment: Your example test case has p=10 which isn't prime

Comment: @xnor Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Convert an integer to Chinese numerals

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

Your task is to convert an integer from 1 to \$10^{52}-1\$ (inclusive).

The characters from 1 to 10 with their Unicode code points are:

```
一 1 U+4E00
二 2 U+4E8C
三 3 U+4E09
四 4 U+56DB
五 5 U+4E94
六 6 U+516D
七 7 U+4E03
八 8 U+516B
九 9 U+4E5D
十 10 U+5341
```

Number greater that that are composed like this:

```
十一 11
十二 12
...
二十 20
二十一 21
二十二 22
...
百 100
百一　101
...
百十 110
...
百九十九 199
二百 200
...
九百九十九 999
千 1000
...
九千九百九十九 9999
一万 10,000
```

This is where it gets interesting, because numbers bigger than 10,000 are groups in groups of four, expressed with 十, 百 and 千. These are the powers we're going to use in this challenge:

```
十 10 U+5341
百 100 U+767E
千 1000 U+5343
万 10^4 U+4E07
億 10^8 U+5104
兆 10^12 U+5146
京 10^16 U+4EAC
垓 10^20 U+5793
秭 10^24 U+79ED
穣 10^28 U+7A63
溝 10^32 U+6E9D
澗 10^36 U+6F97
正 10^40 U+6B63
載 10^44 U+8F09
極 10^48 U+6975
```

Let's go through an example with 123456789123456789 as the input (other algorithms are possible)

- identify groups of four digits, starting from the right: 12,3456,7891,2345,6789
- convert each group: 十二  三千四百五十六  七千八百九十一  二千三百四十五  六千七百八十九
- insert the appropriate multipliers: 十二京三千四百五十六兆七千八百九十一億二千三百四十五万六千七百八十九

### Notes

- A leading ー MAY be dropped before 千 and 百 and MUST be dropped before 十.

### IO format

The input can be an integer in any reasonable format. You can use a string/sequence of characters or a number type, if your language supports it. 128-bit numbers are not large enough, by the way.

### Testcases

```
input output
1 一
2 二
3 三
4 四
5 五
6 六
7 七
8 八
9 九
10 十
15 十五
20 二十
31 三十一
100 百
123　百二十一
1000 千
8346 八千三百四十六
10000 一万
50010 五万十
100000 十万
123456789123456789　十二京三千四百五十六兆七千八百九十一億二千三百四十五万六千七百八十九
1234567891234567891234567891234567891234567891234567 一千二百三十四極五千六百七十八載九千百二十三正四千五百六十七澗八千九百十二溝三千四百五十六穣七千八百九十一禾予二千三百四十五垓六千七百八十九京一千二百三十四兆五千六百七十八億九千百二十三万四千五百六十七
```

Standard code-golf rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals
- This online converter seems to work well: https://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/numbers.cgi
- The Japanese dictionary [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8D%81%E4%BA%8C%E4%BA%AC%E4%B8%89%E5%8D%83%E5%9B%9B%E7%99%BE%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E5%85%AD%E5%85%86%E4%B8%83%E5%8D%83%E5%85%AB%E7%99%BE%E4%B9%9D%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%80%E5%84%84%E4%BA%8C%E5%8D%83%E4%B8%89%E7%99%BE%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%81%E4%BA%94%E4%B8%87%E5%85%AD%E5%8D%83%E4%B8%83%E7%99%BE%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%81%E4%B9%9D) can convert Japanese numberals to western notation

Comment: I assume this is meant to be code-golf? While the tag is technically enough, I think it is better to have a brief inclusion of that in the body of the challenge.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman yes it should be codegolf.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you include the code points for the Unicode characters.

Comment: As someone who is actively learning Japanese, they're called Chinese numerals because they were taken from China's numeral system. Japanese numerals are a whole different, extremely complicated thing.

Comment: "A leading ー MAY be dropped before 千 and 百". They MUST be dropped in Sino-Korean numerals, tho.

Comment: What about 恒河沙, 阿僧祇, 那由他, 不可思議, and 無量大數?

Comment: Mathematica has `IntererName[#, "Words", Language -> "Chinese"]&`, but, unfortunately, it can't handle numbers *this* large :(.

Comment: Can we take input in base 10000? (Usually done when doing big integer multiplication with int32 so seems somehow reasonable)

Answer (score 1):

## [The Double-Castle Numbers™](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205515/the-double-castle-numbers) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

### Divide into 2 isosceles triangles [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given the measures of two of the interior angles of a triangle (`x` and `y`; the other angle can be easily calculated with `180 - x - y`), draw a line segment that cuts this triangle into two isosceles triangles. You need to output the angle measures of both of your triangles.

However, because the base angles are the same, you only need to output the list `[apex angle, base angle]` of the divided triangles for both of the isosceles triangles. You can output the divided triangles in any order.

### An example

```
Say your input is 100, 60.

Let's take a look at the complete triangle first. The triangle looks approximately like this.

   100

60            20

Now we try to divide one of the angles such that two divided triangles are both isosceles triangles.

       100

(40,20)           20

Now our bottom triangle is an isosceles triangle, since both of the base angles
of the bottom triangle are 20. The angle measures of the bottom triangle
looks approximately like this.

       140
20             20

Now, is the top triangle an isosceles triangle?

    100
          40
40

It is an isosceles triangle, because two of the angle measures are 40.

Therefore, for [100, 60], you need to output [[100, 40], [140, 20]].
```

### Example cases

```
[20, 40] -> [[140, 20], [120, 40]]
[45, 45] -> [[90, 45], [90, 45]]
[36, 72] -> [[72, 36], [36, 72]]
[108, 36] -> [[108, 36], [36, 72]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## King+queen vs king checkmate [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

You are given a chess position, represented either in [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) or as a two-dimensional diagram like this (the example test cases will be using the latter format):

```
...k....
........
...K....
.....Q..
........
........
........
........
```

In the examples, `K` represents the white king, `Q` represents the white queen, `k` represents the black king and `.` represents blank space. You may choose different consistent values instead of these characters. You may also input the diagram as a list of lists or in any other way that is allowed by default for two-dimensional arrays.

It is white's move. The position will always be reachable from the starting position by a sequence of valid moves.

You have to find the minimum number of moves White must do to checkmate Black, assuming perfect play by Black.

## Test cases

Incomplete: too many test cases for 1 and no test cases for >1.

```
...k....
........
...K....
...Q....
........
........
........
........
```

Output: 1

```
k.......
........
..K.....
........
........
........
........
.Q......
```

Output: 1

```
k.......
..KQ....
........
........
........
........
........
........
```

Output: 1

Comment: I know it would be a lot different, but have you considered the more general question that allows any (valid) disposition of the three pieces? Then the task would be to find the minimum number of moves to checkmate... Isn't it a bit "tautological" to input a position of which I already know it only takes one move to checkmate? -I most probably know also what this move is-

Comment: Moreover if it happens to be only 1 move from checkmate _(or also, if you want, if the moves can be all determined)_, with this broader task you could totally ask what this _(these)_ move is _(are)_.

Comment: I think asking for the optimal depth to mate in White moves is a better question (far less simple than this, but still much less complicated than a proper chess engine); I'll change the proposal later; it's late here.

Comment: This is ambitious for code golf! Is the point to build an endgame tablebase? at least as much of it as is needed to solve the given test case positions? Test case: wKa1Qb2 bKf5 WTM wins in 10...

Answer (score 1):

### Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

Every TeX user has been warned many times that their [hboxes are terribly underfull or overfull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138). So much [badness](https://i.redd.it/z85vd87240j31.png)! This challenge is to rate how badly underfull or overfull a line of text is for a simplified line wrapper.

**Task**

You're given a space-separated string or list of words. Output the minimal badness achievable for the first line.

The text needs to be wrapped on a line that's 10 characters wide, but it can only be split on spaces, no in the middle of words. Any letter that spills beyond the width counts for 1000 overfull badness each, and each leftover empty position at the end of the line counts for 1000 underfull badness.

**Example**

For input `"Overfull hbox"`, we can keep the word `"hbox"` in the first line for 3000 overfull badness, or wrap it to the second line for 2000 underfull badness which is smaller, so the output is 2000.

```
0123456789

Overfull hbox
          ^^^
Overfull
hbox    ^^
```

Note that we don't care about badness of the second line.

**Details**

The input is a space-separated string or a list of words made of letters `a-zA-Z`. It won't have any words more than 10 letters long, or be more than 20 characters in total. It won't be empty or have any zero-length words.

**Test cases**

TODO

---

**Sandbox:** Is it OK to have a multiplier of 1000 for theme? Should the underfull and overfull badness penalties be different, like 1000 vs 2000?

Comment: In my opinion, this might be a bit too simple for the big badness theme to be worth it. I feel like most golfing languages might spend nearly half their code multiplying by 1000 (throwing it together in Pyth, I got 1/4 used for multiplying). If it was say, the badness of each of the lines it might feel better. I don't feel terribly strongly about this though.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That for the feedback. I'm now thinking the challenge is too simple overall, multiplier or not. What would you think of something like words being able to be broken at certain places in the middle, either explicitly marked or dervied from some property of the letters?

Comment: I think some level of TeX uses hyphens to indicate possible word breaks, but they don't count for the length of words if unused. Adding that may help, while also being on theme?

Answer (score 1):

### Lucky dice rolls

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In pen and paper roleplaying games dice are used for various chance calculations. The usual way to describe a roll is \$n\textbf{d}k\$ where \$n\$ is the number of dice and \$k\$ is the number of faces on a die. For example \$3d6\$ means that you need to roll the classical 6-sided die 3 times (or roll 3 dice at the same time). Both \$n\$ and \$k\$ are positive integers.

Usually the values are then summed and they are used for various game mechanics like chance to hit something or damage calculations.

A lucky roll will mean that you have Fortuna's favor on your side (or against you). Luckiness is an integer number that increases (or decreases) the sum in the following way. The roll is modified to \${(n+|luck|)}\textbf{d}{k}\$ and the sum will be the \$n\$ best (or worst) values. Each die is fair, so they will have the same probability for the outcome of the possible values.

The \$luck\$ can be a negative number, in this case you need to get the \$n\$ worst values for the sum.

#### Input

The integer values for \$n,k,luck\$ in any way.

#### Output

The expected value for the sum of the (un)lucky roll. The [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case) is \$\sum{x_{i} p_{i}}\$ where \$x_{i}\$ is the possible outcome of the sum and \$p_{i}\$ is the probability for \$x_{i}\$ occuring, and \$i\$ indexes all possible outcomes.

#### Examples

```
n,k,luck    expected value
1,6,0       3.5
2,6,0       7
2,6,-1      5.541666666666667
2,6,1       8.458333333333334
2,10,-1     8.525
2,10,1      13.475
```

#### Scoring

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Good luck! ;)

Comment: Probably worth including a definition of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case). To what precision should the output be determined?

Comment: @Dingus Is it now a bit more understandable?

Comment: Yes, that's good, though I'd suggest tweaking the wording a bit: 'The expected value is \$\sum x_ip_i\$ where \$x_i\$ is a possible value for the sum, \$p_i\$ is the probability of that sum occurring, and \$i\$ indexes all possible outcomes.' Perhaps I should rephrase my question about precision - what numeric formats are acceptable for output? Floats are obviously allowed, but do you require a certain number of decimal places? Is it acceptable to output rationals (for languages that support this)? What about 2 integers representing numerator and denominator, respectively?

Comment: hmm, that's a valid point, but I don't know which one it should be.

Answer (score 1):

## [I am surely the fastest!... asymptotically](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206350/i-am-surely-the-fastest-asymptotically) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Posted.

Comment: Slightly related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182733/solve-subset-sum-in-polynomial-time-if-p-np

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate The challenge in your link is slightly more difficult than mine, since prime factorization is not NP-complete. (Godel machines are also a completely different solution)

Answer (score 1):

#### Iterate diagonally over nxn matrix

Given a matrix of size n, output the matrix into another matrix of size n such that:

- the outputted matrix, when traversed diagonally,will result in the original matrix.

For example, taking this 3x3 matrix, we arrive at our solution:
[image]

Which is checked by following the line beginning at 1:
[image]

### Specifications:

- The matrix will always be square
- You must output a grid with the same size as you were given (e.g. Not as a triangle)
- Mark the end of each row with a delimiter such as `\n`  or  .

### Examples:

#### Example 1

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
1 3 6
2 5 8
4 7 9
```

We can check the output by iterating over the array diagonally (follow the arrows for steps 1-5), which will give us the original matrix.

```
  ↗ ↗ ↗
1 ↗ ↗ ↗
2 ↗ ↗ ↗
3  4 5
```

#### Example 2

Input:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

Output:

```
a c f j
b e i m  
d h l o
g k n p
```

We can check this by iterating the array in steps `1-7` which outputs the given array.

```
  ↗ ↗ ↗ ↗
1 ↗ ↗ ↗ ↗
2 ↗ ↗ ↗ ↗
3 ↗ ↗ ↗ ↗
4  5 6 7
```

Hint:

Looking at the coordinates, we can see a pattern:

```
(0,0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 0) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 0) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 1) -> (2,2)
```

Comment: Do the matrices always consist of one character per cell?

Comment: they don't have to, but that can be a specification. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the title could be a bit more descriptive, like "put the contents of a matrix into its antidiagonals". Then you could add a definition of the antidiagonals, and then a description of how you traverse the matrix to get the ordering for the antidiagonalization.

Answer (score 1):

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206470/the-one-counting-challenge-to-rule-them-all).

Comment: It would ease readability if all of the test cases were in a single code block, with empty lines in between. Then you can add the explanations afterward for cases that really need it.

Comment: Is there a limit to the depth of the tree?

Comment: The problem statement involves a bunch of high-level math terms, which can deter some people. If possible, the challenge would be more approachable if you add an alternate definition, e.g. relating isomorphism to permutations (kinda) of the underlying set. For the explanation of the first case, it would be good to rewrite each line using normal infix notation, e.g. `(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)` and `x+(-x) = 0`.

Comment: @fireflame241 I hid the technical details. And could you please explain why I should put a limit to the depth? In what ways does that make the challenge better? ;)

Comment: I was just wondering. A golfer might be able to optimize for a limit depth of 2, but it's more interesting to have an arbitrary rank

Comment: @fireflame241 After some thoughts, it is clear that every theory can be translated to one that has a limit depth of 2 ;) Also every practically interesting case happens at depth 2. So I think I'll add that.

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 1):

## Write an expect program

If you're not already familiar, expect is a Tcl extension that makes it easier to script interactions with programs. It allows you to spawn a process, send lines to it, and wait for expected output before continuing.

### Challenge

The aim of this challenge is to write a very simple implementation of expect in as few bytes as possible (code golf). It should parse a script, with commands separated by newlines. Then it should use this script to interact with a program.

Here are the commands for this implementation:

- `spawn <cmd>`: spawn a process.
- `write <line>`: write a line into the process' input.
- `expect <line>`: expect a substring from the process' output. No timeout is necessary, if the line never appears it is OK for the program to hang.
- `print <line>`: print something to stdout.

You can assume that only one `spawn` will be found in the script, and that it will appear before any `write` or `expect`. If your language of choice doesn't have the ability to spawn processes, you can write a helper program in a different language that can pipe input and output through your main program. How you do this is left up to you.

Example script:

```
spawn /bin/bash
write whoami
expect root
write uname -a
expect Linux
print i am root on Linux
```

Output:

```
this is Linux
```

or

```
spawn /bin/bash
write uname -a
expect Windows
print this is Windows
```

(no output.)

### Restrictions

In order to keep things fresh, the use of the standard `expect` utility or any libraries that emulate `expect` functionality (such as `pexpect` on Python or `jest` on Node) are not allowed. The idea is that the bulk of the functionality should be written in the program and not handled in a library.

Comment: Will the script always have 4 commands, namely those 4 in that order?

Comment: While prohibiting the standard `expect` utility is probably unambiguous, prohibiting `expect`-*like* libraries [could potentially be problematic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/43319) because there's no objective way to judge if any given feature is `expect`-like. I could claim that *addition* is `expect`-like, and you'd be hard pressed to counter that.

Comment: The script could have more commands. I will update the examples to reflect that change. As far as the library restrictions, I could remove them - I do see where it could lead to being a problem. Perhaps I could make it more unambiguous by mentioning specific libraries (one that comes to mind is python-pexpect.)

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about the order of the commands?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that spawn will come before any command that needs the process. It should be updated now.

Comment: What should be done if the expect string is not found?

Comment: It was mentioned above but for clarity:
'No timeout is necessary, if the line never appears it is OK for the program to hang.'

Answer (score 1):

## Count faces in ASCII art [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Here's a 2x2 ASCII art face:

```
oo
__
```

Here's a 3x3 ASCII art face:

```
o o
   
___
```

Here's a 4x4 ASCII art face:

```
o  o
    
    
____
```

Your task is to count faces in an ASCII art.

Here's something closer to an actual specification.

The bottom of any face must be a contiguous horizontal row of underscores, such that cells to the right and to the left of it do not contain underscores. If the row is considered as the bottom row of an ASCII square, then that square forms a face if and only if its bottom row is all underscores, its upper left and upper right corners are `o`s, and the rest is whitespace.

You may assume all lines in the input to be padded on the right with whitespace to an equal length. Faces cannot be smaller than 2x2.

[todo: more test cases]

```
o o
   oo
_____
```

Output: 0

## Sandbox stuff

Is it clear what is considered a face and what is not?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/206600/68261

Comment: @fireflame241 I know about that challenge, and I don"t think solutions will be similar at all.

Answer (score 1):

## The almost impossible chessboard puzzle [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [puzzle-solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-solver) [error-correction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction)

### Background

> Prisoner 1 walks in, sees a chessboard (8x8) where each square has a coin on top, flipped either to heads or tails. The warden places the key under one of the squares, which prisoner 1 sees. Before prisoner 1 leaves, he must turn over one and only one coin.  Prisoner 2 then walks in and is supposed to be able to figure out which squares the key is in just by looking at the arrangement of coins.

The prisoners are granted a reward if prisoner 2 correctly tells the location of the key.

### Task

Write two program/functions:

- One for prisoner 1, which outputs the location of the coin to flip given the current board state and the location of the key
- One for prisoner 2, which outputs the location of the key given the board state after prisoner 1 doing the flip.

If both the solutions are function they may share code with an auxiliary function, though the solutions may not share any information.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins

---

*Heavily inspired by [The almost impossible chessboard puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=as7Gkm7Y7h4) and [The impossible chessboard puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTJI_WuZSwE)*

## Sandbox

- Should I include the [error-correction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction) tag
- Any more tags I should add
- Is something not clear

Also pretty sure this will require a lot of rewording before it can be asked

Comment: Can the two solutions share code, for example by having two functions that both call a third auxiliary function?

Comment: Yes, the two solutions can share code but they cannot share information. Updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Can the auxiliary function be one of the programs? Can both of the programs be the same (and only counted once for bytes, having different behavior based on whether a second argument is passed)?

Answer (score 1):

## Infinite Mirrors Quine

This challenge is to create a program that prints out code that prints the original. Basically, this program should take an input, check if it's A, and if so, run section A. Otherwise, if it's B, run section B. Finally, if it's neither, print nothing. Section A should print the code in section B, and section B should print the code in section A. Section A's code and section b's code should not be identical. Shortest code wins!

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges: Most kinds of generalised quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595/46076)

Comment: This doesn't print a transformed version of source code, it prints a different section of the source code

Answer (score 1):

## Continuous Everywhere, Differentiable Nowhere

### Objective

Build the Weierstrass function \$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n n x)\$, where \$a \in (0,1)\$, \$b\$ is an odd positive integer, and \$ab > 1 + 1.5\pi\$.

### What's the fuss?

The Weierstrass function is an example of a function that is continuous everywhere, but differentiable nowhere.

### Format

Using floating-point number is permitted. Though it will be preferred to use a datatype that is able to represent arbitrary real numbers.

### Rules

\$a\$ and \$b\$ are up to your choice, as long as they satisfy the conditions.

For every \$x \in \mathbb{R}\$, evaluation of \$f(x)\$ must halt.

### Note

The fact that the function above is defined as an infinite series might seem to contradict the rule, but it actually doesn't. The Weierstrass function is [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function), implying that it is possible to halt for every input. In particular, if it were to be implemented over floating-point numbers, it suffices to stop summing when the summand becomes denormal.

Comment: I really doubt that the Weierstrass function is computable since its domain is real numbers and computer programs can only compute a select few functions on arbitrary real input.  The Weierstrass function is very likely computable on some restricted domains like the rational numbers.  Really this question has a some issues with the fact that continuity and differentiabilty are usually discussed in the context of real numbers, but does not require that it work on actual real numbers.

Comment: For example as it currently stands I could do something like just output the floating point zero regardless of input.  This is approximates some cewdnw function, in fact it comes arbitrarily close to approximating an infinite number of cewdnw functions.  For example just the Weierstrass function multiplied by a really small positive number.

Comment: However if you do restrict it to real numbers you run into the problem that very few functions are computable on real numbers.  (The issue here is that a program on real numbers must be ready to accept an infinite string of input).  I suggest restricting your domain to something like rational numbers, but note that this alters continuity and differntiability in subtle ways so it is not a simple patch.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Comment: while this problem is solvable in polynomial time, I guess the code-golf submissions are going to take exponential time.

Comment: @user202729 Do you actually have a polynomial tome algorithm?

Comment: Yes. -- -- -- -- -- --

Comment: @user202729 What is it?

Comment: Iterate over substrings of the string, then check if it satisfies with `f(left, right, prefix)` = (can `eraser[:prefix]` be formed from `string[left:right]` by repeated erase operations?) At most this is O(n^6).

Comment: I cannot understand your notation so I do not understand your algorithm, but I will say it seems to me that checking whether an eraser erases a string should naïvely take O(2^n) since in strings like "ototoo" it matters which "oto" you erase first thus you have to branch between the possible choices.

Comment: The notation is like Python, `string[left:right]` is character from left..right (inclusive), `eraser[:prefix] is `eraser[0:prefix]`, characters are 0-indexed.

Comment: It's possible to compute each `f(left, right, prefix)`  value from O(n) other values (dynamic programming) and there's only O(n^3) possible parameters.

Comment: @user202729 Ok, It looked like python but it didn't make any sense as python code, might you actually write this in python?  It still doesn't make a whole lot of sense and even then feels like it should be O(2^n) because of "can [...] be formed from [...] by repeated erase operations?" seems to be an O(2^n) check to me.

Comment: `f=lambda left, right, prefix: string[left:right]==eraser[:prefix] or (left!=right and (string[right-1]==eraser[prefix-1] and f(left, right-1, prefix-1) or f(left, right, len(eraser) or any(f(left, middle, prefix) and f(middle, right, 0) for middle in range(left+1, right))))`, something like that, with caching.

Comment: Looks like this problem (or a similar one) has already appeared somewhere else. See https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14090

Comment: @user202729 Ok so I've spent a little while unpacking that algoirthm in the blog post and it seems to be O(2^n) unless there is some invariant I am missing.  I will say I still do not have the slightest understanding of your algorithm.

Comment: About the blog: if you understood it then there is no way it can be 2^n because there are only n^2 different states (possible parameter values)  of the dp function .

Comment: @user202729 The issue is that calculating a cell is not contsant time sometimes we are required to solve the entire problem again on a smaller string to fill in a cell.  You can make schemes where the number of these cells is linear witht he size of the program, hence exponential time overall.   however at this point I have found a dynamic programming algo that does this in O(n^4), so it doesn't matter much to me any more.

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 1):

### Ant Storage Labyrinth [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

#### Description

Using a simplified model, the place where ants store their food can be thought of as an \$n\times n\$ matrix. Each entry of the matrix is an integer that encodes how *full* that specific spot is, according to the following correspondence:

- `0` denotes an empty spot (the ants can add two more units of food),
- `1` denotes a half-filled spot (the ants can add one more unit of food),
- `2` denotes a filled spot (no more food can be stored in there).

Imagine an ant carrying \$f\$ units of food, that enters the "storage room" at a specific position (row \$i\$, column \$j\$ of the matrix). The ant can move one unit left, right, up or down with each step, and it can drop \$2-q\$ units of food at each spot it walks over (where \$q\$ is the initial capacity of that spot – either `0`, `1` or `2` as described above). Your task is to find the length of the shortest path the ant can choose in order to store all \$f\$ units of food.

#### Example

Let's say that the ant carries \$4\$ units and enters the following storage room (\$6\times 6\$ matrix) at position \$(3,3)\$ (1-indexed):

$$\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&1\\1&2&\color{red}{1}&2&1&1\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]$$

It drops \$1\$ unit right where it starts (\$3\$ left), then it has four optimal choices:

- 3 moves to the right, and 1 up,

  $$\longrightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&1\\1&2&\color{green}{2}&\color{red}{2}&1&1\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&1\\1&2&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{red}{1}&1\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&1\\1&2&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{red}{1}\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\\\longrightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&\color{red}{1}\\1&2&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}0&2&2&2&2&2\\2&1&2&2&2&\color{green}{2}\\1&2&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}&\color{green}{2}\\2&1&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\1&2&2&1&2&2\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
- 2 moves to the left, and 2 up,
- 1 move up, 2 left, and one up,
- 1 move up, 1 left, 1 up, 1 left.

All of these require \$4\$ steps, so the final answer is \$\boxed{4}\$.

### Test cases

*In progress*. I need help coming up with interesting test cases / maybe a verification program.

Answer (score 1):

## Successive operator sequences [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

A successive operator sequence (made up terminology) is a sequence of the form \$a(n + 1) = a(n) \text{ op } n\$ where `op` cycles through a set of operators and \$a(n)\$ represents the \$n\$th term of the sequence.

For examples, if we set the operators to addition, multiplication and subtraction and \$a(1) = 1\$. then we will get the following sequence (which is also [A047908](https://oeis.org/A047908)):

```
a(1)                    = 1
a(2) = a(1) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
a(3) = a(2) * 2 = 2 * 2 = 4
a(4) = a(3) - 3 = 4 - 3 = 1
a(5) = a(4) + 4 = 1 + 4 = 5
a(6) = a(5) * 5 = 5 * 5 = 25
```

### Task

Write a program/function to output the \$n\$th term of a successive operator sequence given its initial term and operators.

Operators your program/function must support:

- multiplication
- addition
- subtraction
- integer division (rounded towards negative infinity)

### Input Format

The operators are inputted as a string or array of character where each character represents an operator, you may choose your own mapping of character to operator.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins.

### Testcases

```
# first term, operators, n  ->  nth term
0,   ["+", "-", "*", "/"], 6   ->  4
1,   ["+", "*", "-"],      1   ->  1
1,   ["+", "*", "-"],      3   ->  4
1,   ["+", "*", "-"],      10  ->  199
1,   ["*", "+", "-"],      7   ->  -1
50,  ["*", "+", "-"],      1   ->  50
50,  ["*", "+", "-"],      4   ->  49
-10, ["*", "/", "-"],      5   ->  -32
-10, ["*", "/", "-"],      3   ->  -5
1,   ["+", "+", "*"],      5   ->  16
2,   ["+", "*"],           5   ->  36
0,   ["+"],                3   ->  3
```

---

*Inspired by the sequence [A047908](https://oeis.org/A047908)*

Comment: Suggested test cases: only one operation; duplicate operations (like `["+","+","-"]`); more than 4 operations. Also, should integer division round toward zero, toward negative infinity, or something else?

Comment: Does each string have to be one byte?

Comment: @fireflame, they have to be a single character not a single byte.

Comment: Why rounding division towards negative infinity? A lot of languages round integer division towards zero and this will add complexity just to do that. Notice that A047908 doesn't use division at all so why add it and make it a problem? Maybe even make it optional which way your answer does it as long as it's stated.

Answer (score 1):

### The ASCII character countdown! [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

Your task is simple: Choose any printable ASCII character that's not chosen in the previous answers. And then, you need to print your chosen character in your program to standard output. (You can ONLY print your chosen character, without printing other garbage to STDOUT)

### The catch

Let's say you picked `x` as your chosen character, and your answer is the answer numbered `y`. You have to insert `y` `x`'s into the previous source code, at any position you like. For the first answer, the previous answer is the empty program.

### An example

Answers have to start with the number 1. So for example, I chose the character `#`, and I posted a 1 byte answer in /// that prints the `#` mark.

```
#
```

And then, the second answer (numbered 2) has to insert 2 of their picked `x` character into the previous source code, such that the modified code will print their `x` character. So assume this is written in Keg:

```
x#x
```

And then, the third answer has to do the same, and so on, until 95 is reached.

### The winning criterion & other rules

- The first user whose answer stays without a succeeding answer for a month wins the challenge. If that's not satisfied, the first person who reaches the number 95 wins the challenge.
- You are not allowed to put any other character in your code other than printable ASCII characters.
- You need to wait for an hour before posting a chaining answer.
- You need to wait 2 answers before you post a new answer after your submission.
- Please make sure your answer is valid. If yours is not valid, chaining answers aren't allowed to be posted.
- The answers are allowed to be in different languages.
- Each submission doesn't have to be in a unique language.
- You could *only* insert `y` `x`'s into the source code.

Comment: Can the answers be in different langauges?

Comment: What is the motivation for the number 95?

Comment: This isn't a radiation hardening challenge, as those require programs to still work / do something different if any single character is removed.

Comment: @fireflame241 Because there are 95 ASCII characters of course...

Comment: Must we *only* insert `y` `x`s, or may we also insert other (printable ASCII) characters apart from our chosen character? If the latter, are the additional characters limited to those not already used in previous answers?

Comment: "I chose the character ?" -> "I chose the character #"?

Comment: "has to insert their picked x character into the previous source code," -> edit this part too.

Comment: @Dingus Now you may only insert y `x`s.

Comment: "I chose the character ?" has crept back in. Other than that it's clear now. (Seems difficult too, but maybe not in the golfing langs - I don't know.)

Answer (score 1):

## Error Once, Hello World Twice

Your task here is to write a Hello World program that, (no, this is not Do X Without Y!) contains two exact copies of the same string. to avoid trivial solutions like `print "Hello World!"#` your program must error out with only one copy.

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Sandbox

- Wording?
- Tags?
- Length?
- Interesting enough to be posted?

Comment: I double the source code, you print hello world? (I'm not saying this is a dupe, I'm asking if that accurately summaries the challenge.)

Comment: @Lyxal Yep. (15chars)

Comment: What if, rather than erroring out with one copy, make it so that it's valid if it prints out anything other than "Hello world"?

Comment: @Beefster Maybe... But that's probably not what I'm intending. I might consider later.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive this also reminds me of my [2 cats in a quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/165929/45613) challenge from a while ago. My main concern here is that "erroring out" is nebulous and different for every language. You could also make it so that the program must print *nothing* unless it's duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

## CoGo Rally

There's a game called [Robo Rally](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18/roborally), in which players "program" their robots five moves ahead, then simultaneously perform the moves, one at a time. The robots move over a "factory floor" grid, with the aim being to reach certain points on the board, in sequence, before the other robots do the same.

## Game Rules

For the purposes of this challenge, the rules will be simplified as follows:

- Each robot starts with 6 lives
- Each robot has a different, randomly assigned starting position (out of a fixed set of starting positions)
- The aim of the game is to reach all three checkpoints in the assigned order, before any other robot does the same.

### Movement Options

Each turn, your robot can make any one of the following movements:

- Rotate Clockwise 90 degrees
- Rotate Counter-clockwise 90 degrees
- Rotate 180 degrees
- Move Forward One
- Move Forward Two
- Move Forward Three [can only be used once until the next checkpoint is met]
- Reverse One (and stay facing the same way)
- Stay Still and gain 1 life, up to the maximum of 6

Your moves are pre-programmed in blocks of five, so choose carefully! The board may well be in a very different state in five moves time to what you think it will be.

Additionally, each movement is assigned a priority from 1-100. When you choose your block of five movements (you may use each movement any number of times, except the "move forward three", to form your five total movements) and the order they will occur in, you are also given five random numbers 1-100 to assign - one to each movement. Higher numbers will take priority where movements would cause two robots to enter the same space, for example.

### Board Items

The board contains the following items:

- Floor - the default tile on the board. No special effect.
- Walls - block a robot's path. If a robot moves forward or backward into a wall, it wastes that move (i.e. stays still, but doesn't gain a life). If the robot used "Move Forward Two", for example, it may be possible that the Robot can only move Forward One, and then stops infront of a wall, wasting the second part of the movement.
- Laser gun - fire in a straight line in a specific direction until they hit a wall or a robot. If a robot is ontop of a laser gun, it will be hit but the laser won't fire further. While moving forward two or three, a robot may pass over the path of a laser gun without being affected by it.
- Conveyor Belts - at the end of a turn (single movement option), a conveyor belt will move the robot one space in the direction the conveyor is pointing. Doesn't block lasers. Conveyor belts NEVER ROTATE ROBOTS, even if they move the robot in a different direction to the one it is facing. While moving forward two or three, a robot may move over a conveyor belt without being affected by it.
- Checkpoints (1,2,3) - act as a save point on the Robot's path and also heals all of a robot's lives and resets their use of the "Move Forward Three" action, the first time the checkpoint is visited. Checkpoints must be visited sequentially to be activated. Acts as a piece of floor in all other respects. Robots must END THEIR TURN ON THE CHECKPOINT, after interaction with other Robots; and not just pass over it.
- Holes - move the robot back to the previously visited checkpoint, or start position. Robot loses half its remaining life, rounded down. Holes act immediately, as soon as the robot enters the space - it doesn't wait for the "board interactions" part of the turn order.

### Interactions

Objects interact as follows:

- If a Robot moves into a space where another robot already exists, the other robot is shoved (moved) in the direction that the first robot was moving, one space; unless there is a wall or laser in the way. This effect may stack if multiple robots are in a line (i.e. all robots are shoved one space). This may cause a robot to fall into a hole or onto a conveyor belt.
- Moving off the edge of the board has the same effect as moving into a hole
- If a Laser fires and hits a robot, the robot stops the laser beam, and takes one damage.
- If a robot is facing another robot in a straight line with nothing blocking in between (i.e. no walls or other robots), the target robot takes 1 damage

  - Therefore If two robots are facing towards each other with nothing blocking in between (i.e. no walls or other robots), both robots take one damage.

### Turn Order

1. determine (program) 5 movement options
2. determine Priorities (1-100) for these five turns
3. The programmed actions occur:
   a. The first movement occurs for each player, in priority order from highest to lowest. Holes are acted on immediately (a robot cannot pass over a hole).
   b. Robot Interactions are resolved (e.g. if one robot shoves another one)
   c. Board Items act (lasers, conveyor belts, checkpoints)
   i. If a robot loses all of its lives, it returns to the previous checkpoint (or start) with half lives (rounded up) and must sit out the remainder of the round
   d. Robots fire
   i. If a robot loses all of its lives, it returns to the previous checkpoint (or start) with half lives (rounded up) and must sit out the remainder of the round
   e. Repeat for the remaining 4 movements
4. Repeat until one robot has reached all three checkpoints sequentially, or all robots have lost their lives

## The Challenge

Your robot must take the board (as a 2D array), and a seed for the Random number generator; and play the game on the given board.

The board is guaranteed to be solveable (there will always be a path from the start to each of the checkpoints)

## Sample Board

[image]

[image]

The above board would be represented in an array as follows:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,LU,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,LL,2,LR,0,0,W,0]
[H,CL,CL,CL,CL,CL,CL,CL,CL,CL,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,CR,CR,CR,CR,CR,CR,H]
[0,W,0,0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,W,0,0,0,0,W,0,W,0,0,0]
[1,W,0,0,0,0,CR,CR,CD,0,W,3]
[0,W,CR,CR,CR,0,CU,H,CD,W,0,0]
[0,LL,CR,CR,CR,CR,CU,CU,CL,0,0,0]
[0,0,S,S,S,S,0,0,W,0,0,0]
```

Where

```
Cx = Conveyor (x=Up, Down, Left, Right)
Lx = Laser gun (x=Up, Down, Left, Right)
S = Start
1,2,3 = Checkpoints
W = Wall
H = Hole
0 = Floor
```

## Sandbox Questions

Should this be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), where you implement your robot in the least code possible; or [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), or something else? If KotH, I've never set one before so some advice would be appreciated!

Comment: (if this is code golf) is it guaranteed that there exists a solution on every boards? Or only boards such that a solution exists are valid input?

Comment: Whether KotH or codegolf, the board will always be solvable (i.e. In all cases all of the checkpoints will be accessible, and there will be at least one path from any starting point to each of the checkpoints)

Answer (score 1):

## Posted: [Antisymmetry of a Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/208982/antisymmetry-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Mathematica: `AntisymmetricMatrixQ` (of course, a non-built-in solution can be much shorter).

Answer (score 1):

## Paper folding. Posted [HERE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/208919/paper-folding-for-the-win)

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 1):

## The Dungeon Number Sequence [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

#### Introduction

The [dungeon numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNx3JxRhnZE) are introduced by Numberphile, denoting a chain of base conversions. A dungeon number is denoted in the form $$a_{b_{c_{d_\cdots}}}$$ where all numbers involved are integers with at least two digits. When interpreting the values, each base conversion \$a_b\$ is treated as from base \$b\$ to base-10.

There are two types of dungeons, one starting from \$10\$ to \$n\$ from top to bottom, i.e. $$10_{11_{12_{\cdots_n}}}$$ increasing \$1\$ for each deeper layer, and one starting from \$n\$ to \$10\$ from top to bottom, i.e. $$n_{(n-1)_{(n-2)_{\cdots_{10}}}}$$ decreasing \$1\$ for each deeper layer. Each dungeon has two interpretations, top down, i.e. $$(((10_{11})_{12})_\cdots)_n$$, and bottom up, i.e. $$10_{(11_{(12_{(\cdots_n)})})}$$, producing 4 dungeon number sequences in total.

#### Example

Considering $$10_{(11_{(12_{13})})}$$. The conversion is bottom up. First \$12_{13}\$ is converted to \$15_{10}\$. Then \$11_{15}\$ is converted to \$16_{10}\$. Finally \$10_{16}\$ is converted to \$16_{10}\$, and this is the value for \$n=13\$.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function, given an integer \$n>=10\$ as input, output either the value of the dungeon number sequence at \$n\$, or the whole sequence from \$10\$ up to \$n\$ inclusive. You may choose any sequence from the 4 sequences, but you must state which you have chosen. You must not hardcode the values; your code must work theoretically for all integer \$n>=10\$.

#### Values

```
n                                  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17   18   19    20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type 1 (((10_11)_12)_...)_n        10  11  13  16  20  30  48  76  132  420  1640
Type 2 10_(11_(12_(..._n)))        10  11  13  16  20  25  31  38   46   55    65
Type 3 (((n_(n-1))_(n-2))_...)_10  10  11  13  16  20  28  45  73  133  348  4943
Type 4 n_((n-1)_((n-2)_(..._10)))  10  11  13  16  20  25  31  38   46   55   110
```

#### Sample IO

- Type 1 (\$(((10_{11})_{12})_\cdots)_n\$)

  ```
  15 => 30
  20 => 1640
  25 => 19563802363305
  ```
- Type 2 (\$10_{(11_{(12_{(\cdots_n)})})}\$)

  ```
  15 => 25
  20 => 65
  25 => 943
  ```
- Type 3 (\$(((n_{(n-1)})_{(n-2)})_\cdots)_{10}\$)

  ```
  15 => 28
  20 => 4943
  25 => 1092759075796059
  ```
- Type 4 (\$n_{((n-1)_{((n-2)_{(\cdots_{10})})})}\$)

  ```
  15 => 25
  20 => 110
  25 => 3577
  ```

#### Winning Criteria

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code for each language wins. No default loopholes.

Answer (score 1):

## LaTeX Fractions

Inspired by [a TeX SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557846/interpret-a-bc-as-fracabc).

LaTeX uses `\frac{a}{b}` to represent `a/b`, which is very unintuitive. Now you have a piece of paper (as in "research paper") which happens to use the `a/b` format, and your task is to convert it to the LaTeX format.

[to be continued]

Comment: @RahulVerma Nested fractions?

Answer (score 1):

## Find a 3-Language Polyglot [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

What I had in mind was that cops would create a polyglot with in 3 languages (languages A, B, and C). When run in A, the program would print the name of language B; when run in language B, the program would print the name of language C; and when run in C, it would print the name of language A.

Cops have to provide the names of these 3 languages, as well as their original polyglot's characters scrambled in no particular order. <s>as well as a valid program in A that has the same behavior as the polyglot (prints the name of B). This program must be able to be created by deleting characters from the original polyglot, i.e., all the letters in it are included in the hidden polyglot.</s>

Given the languages and the scrambled program<s>and the sample program</s>, robbers have to find the polyglot (or a polyglot that has the same behavior as the one the cop wrote).

### Rules

- Any language chosen must be able to be run on TIO, repl.it, ideone, or someplace else online. If the language is obscure, please provide a link to some such website.
- Any language used must have documentation on Esolangs, Wikipedia, GitHub, or someplace else. Unless the language is very commonly used and has tons of tutorials everywhere, such as Java, Haskell, or C, please provide a link to documentation. Any feature used in the program must be included in that documentation - it shouldn't be something people have to dig through layers of source code to find.

Questions for meta:

- Is this too easy/hard? Should I not include the extra A program? Should I only make it for 2 languages?
- Is there anything unclear about the instructions? How can I improve the phrasing?
- Should cops also give the length of their programs as an extra hint?

Comment: one thing to consider: you would need some way of restricting languages that are allowed. Otherwise people could just make up their own languages or use really, really obscure languages.

Comment: IIRC, the usual way to limit the language list is to specify "the language should be on at least one of Wikipedia, TIO, or esolangs.org", though esolangs is already crazy these days.

Comment: @Bubbler Yup, I've edited my question with some restrictions now

Answer (score 1):

## How Many Notches Are On Texas Red's Pistol?

The song, *Big Iron*, by Marty Robbins, is about an Arizona Ranger who rode into the town of Agua Fria to take the outlaw Texas Red alive (or maybe dead), armed with only the Big Iron (a .45 revolver) on his hip. Texas Red, despite being only 24 years old, is extremely dangerous, having already taken out 20 men who have tried to go after him. As a point of pride, he's carved out a notch on his pistol for each one. The song counts the notches on Texas Red's pistol as "one and nineteen more". After listening to the song a couple times, two questions crossed my mind:

1. What about the other numbers that add up to twenty?
2. What if the Ranger wasn't the 21st person to try?

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer, *N*, the total notches on Texas Red's pistol, and another number *A* (also an positive integer), output a number *B* such that *B + A = N*. In the context of the song, it should read "*A* and *B* more".

### The Catch

The song still has to be intact without sub-dividing any beats. That is, the number of syllables in the phrase "A and B more" must add up to 5. If it doesn't, output the string "oops". You may assume

- *0 < A < N < 20*
- *1 < N*

### Examples

```
N   A   B (output)

20  1   19   ("One and nineteen more.")
19  2   oops ("Two and seventeen more" has 6 syllables)
11  7   4    ("Seven and four more.")
```

### Syllable Counts

The numbers, from one to nineteen, have syllable counts as follows: one (1), two (1), three (1), four (1), five (1), six (1), seven (2), eight (1), nine (1), ten (1), eleven (3), twelve (1), thirteen (2), fourteen (2), fifteen (2), sixteen (2), seventeen (3), eighteen (2), and nineteen (2). No synonyms are accepted, such as "aught more" for "zero more".

### Scoring

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): Shortest code in bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply.

---

#### Meta Stuff:

I hope this is interesting enough. I thought just a normal subtraction problem would be too boring.

Is "oops" a good distinguishing output?

Answer (score 1):

## Show an integer, in digits of your choice

### Input

A string representing digit characters, and a nonnegative integer.

### How?

We shall show the integer in [positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), where the string has the digit characters. Assuming the string is zero-indexed, the \$n\$th character shall represent \$n\$. The length of the string is the base.

For example, `"0123456789"` will show the integer in the standard decimal representation.

### Rules

- The string is assumed to have at least 2 characters.
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

### Examples

Beware of the zero!

#### Binary representation

Given `"01"` as the string:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & “0” \\
4 & “100” \\
8 & “1000” \\
15 & “1111” \\
16 & “10000” \\
23 & “10111” \\
42 & “101010”
\end{array}
$$

#### Devanagari representation

Given `"०१२३४५६७८९"` (U+0966 – U+096F) as the string:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & “०” \\
4 & “४” \\
8 & “८” \\
15 & “१५” \\
16 & “१६” \\
23 & “२३” \\
42 & “४२”
\end{array}
$$

#### Duodecimal representation

Given `"0123456789↊↋"` (The last two characters are U+218A and U+218B) as the string:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & “0” \\
4 & “4” \\
8 & “8” \\
15 & “13” \\
16 & “14” \\
23 & “1↋” \\
42 & “36”
\end{array}
$$

### Ungolfed solution

#### Haskell

```
showIntArb :: String -> Int -> ShowS
showIntArb "" _ = error "showIntArb: No given digit"
showIntArb (d:_) 0 = showChar d
showIntArb ds n = let
    appendDigit ints = if length ints <= n
        then appendDigit $ do
            d <- ds
            int <- ints
            return (d : int)
        else ints
    in showString (appendDigit (fmap return ds) !! n)
```

Comment: so this is a base encoding question, with symbol replacement, right?

Comment: @Razetime Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

## Haiku Quine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

A haiku is a type of poetry originating from Japan following a simple pattern: 5 syllables on the first line, 7 syllables on the second, and 5 syllables on the third. Traditionally, haikus also include some reference to nature or seasons, but we'll ignore tradition for the sake of this challenge.

Your task is to create a quine which has some reasonable pronunciation in the form of a haiku.

For example, consider this loophole-abusing (and thus non-competing) Python quine:

```
0+0
with open(__file__) as fp:
    print(fp.read())
```

To be read as:

```
ze-ro plus ze-ro
with o-pen file as F P
print F P dot read
```

## Rules and Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

- Standard rules and banned loopholes apply
- Include a reasonable haiku pronunciation alongside your code (yes, this is inherently subjective and open-ended)

---

NOTE: may be better as a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

Comment: what's the standard for xxd output here?

Answer (score 1):

## Convert A String To Shorthand

[Shorthand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand) has been used for hundreds of years to compress and speed up the speed at which someone can write down what is said.
It does this using several abbreviating methods; three of which will be used here to compress a sentence.

### Challenge

When given a sentence, alongside a set of 'briefs', 'prefixes' and 'suffixes' (*defined below*), print or return the sentence in its compressed form.

#### Definitions

- **Brief**: A word that can be entirely substituted by another string of characters.
  *I.E. Would: D, Be: B, Able: Ab. "I would be able...": "I D B Ab*
- **Prefix**: The beginning of a word that can be substituted by another string of characters; the prefix will either be joined or dis-joined.
  *After(Joined): Af. Afternoon = Afnoon.

  Enter/Inter/Intra(Dis-joined): N. Internet = N-net*
- **Suffix**: The ending of a word that can be substituted by another string of characters; the suffix will either be joined or dis-joined.
  *ful/ify(Joined): F. Clarify = Clarf

  ification(Dis-joined): F. Clarification = Clar-f*

#### Input Structure

1. The first input will be the sentence to be converted
2. The second input is a collection of the briefs. Each brief is a collection itself, in which the first element represents the shortened form of that brief, while the rest of the elements are all strings that map to the brief. *Example: [ [d, would], [m, much, more], [a, at, an] ]*
3. The third and fourth inputs are collections of prefixes and suffixes. The first element of each prefix/suffix is the shortened form, the second element is a flag (of your choosing) that represents whether it is joined or dis-joined. Everything else are the strings that match the prefix/suffix.
   *Prefix: [ [af, true, after], [n, false, enter, inter, intra] ]

   Suffix: [ [f, true, ful, ify], [f, false, ification] ]*

Sample Input:

```
"a shipment of letters was delivered to the postshop", [["of", "o"], ["t", "to"], ["was", "os"], ["the", "th"]], [["sh", false, "ship"], ["d", true, "de"], ["po", false, "post"]], [["rs", true, "ers"], ["m", true, "ment"], ["d", true, "ed"]]
```

### Rules, Assumptions and Freedoms

- You may assume all input is lowercase letters.
- A brief will always take priority over prefixes and suffixes.
- you can indicate a dis-joined suffix/prefix however you wish, as long as you mention how you are indicating it.
- The input may be rearranged however you like, as long as you specify how your input is structured
- Output may be returned, printed or the nearest equivalent.

### Test Cases

```
"a shipment of letters was delivered to the postshop", [["of", "o"], ["t", "to"], ["was", "os"], ["the", "th"]], [["sh", false, "ship"], ["d", true, "de"], ["po", false, "post"]], [["rs", true, "ers"], ["m", true, "ment"], ["d", true, "ed"]]
```

> a sh-m o lettrs os dliverd t th po-shop

```
"shorthand was once a common skill among woman", [["was", "os"]], [["sh", false, "ship", "short"], ["cm", true, "com"]], [["mn", true, "mon", "man"]]
```

> sh-hand os once a cmmn skill among womn"

```
"the electrician will be able to fix it", [["th", "the"], ["l", "will"], ["b", "be"], ["ab", "able"], "t", "to", "it"]], [["el", false, "electr"]], [["sh", true, "cian", "sion"]]
```

> th el-ish l b ab t fix t

Comment: Looks like a nice challenge, I don't think there's much that needs to `B clar-f-ed`

Answer (score 1):

## Keep the symmetry

**SANDBOX: I am aware that the language in this challenge, as it stands, is quite... fluffy. If anyone could help me firm it up, I would be grateful. Also, would this be better as a cops-and-robbers style challenge, where the cops are trying to make the output more symmetrical, and the robbers make it less symmetrical?**

Given a 2D array of 1s and 0s, flip a 1 to a 0 and output the resulting array.

The output array must be "closer to being symmetrical" than the input.

In the case where the array is already symmetrical, it must still flip a 1 to a 0, breaking as little symmetry as possible - e.g for

```
1,0,1
1,0,1
1,0,1
```

In the above case, changing the top-left `1` to a `0` will break symmetry in both directions, whereas changing the middle-left `1` will only break symmetry one way.

The output must be in the same form as the input (so that your program or function could take it in again).

#### What is symmetry?

I am talking about reflectional symmetry along both the horizontal and vertical axes.

Where the array has an even number of entries in a row/column, the axis is between the two central rows/columns:

```
1,0,|,0,1
1,0,|,0,1
-,-,-,-,-
1,0,|,0,1
1,0,|,0,1
```

otherwise it's down the middle of the middle row/column (and the numbers in that row/column count on both sides).

```
   |  
 1,0,1
-1,0,1-
 1,0,1
   |
```

#### Some Examples

Each pair of grids below is input .. output, which then becomes the next input, etc. iteratively:

```
1,0,0,1      1,0,0,1      1,0,0,1      1,0,0,1      1,0,0,0      0,0,0,0      0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0  ..  0,0,0,0  ..  0,0,0,0  ..  0,0,0,0  ..  0,0,0,0  ..  0,0,0,0  ..  0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1      1,0,0,1      0,0,0,1      0,0,0,0      0,0,0,0      0,0,0,0      0,0,0,0
```

```
1,1,1      1,0,1      1,0,1      1,0,1      1,0,1
1,1,1  ..  1,1,1  ..  1,0,1  ..  0,0,1  ..  0,0,0
1,0,1      1,0,1      1,0,1      1,0,1      1,0,1
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Is the program supposed to find the shortest path, or any path? Are we supposed to display each step? Should the choice of flipping a 1 to a 0 be random, or can it be calculated? A reference implementation would be very useful in this question.

Comment: The program is only supposed to flip one, calculated, bit from 1 to 0 and return the new grid. so iterative calls to the program would ultimately lead to all 0s. I guess I'm unclear exactly how I want the concept to be translated into a challenge, which is why I put the sandbox text at the top

Comment: _The program must be trying to make the array symmetrical_ This needs to be defined precisely. What does it mean that the program "tries" to make it symmetrical? That repeated application of the program eventaully gives a symmetrical array? That it does it in a "small" (to be defined) number of steps? Same with _as easy as possible_: this needs to be defined precisely. I'm afraid I don't get the main idea of the challenge, actually

Answer (score 1):

## Balanced Beams

Here are some examples of beams that balance:

```
X Y A   | X Y B Y
--+-----+---+---+
  |         |   |
X X   Y Y   Y X X
--+---- ----+-- +

A X X Y | A B Y Y
+---+---+-+-----+
|   |     |     |
B A | A AAB B   A
+ --+-- --+--   +

X Y X X | Y B   X
+-+-+---+---+----
| | |       |
Y A X Y Y X X X X
+ + + ------+----
```

The diagram will always be 17 characters wide and the top beam always balances in its centre. The other `+`s on the top beam indicate the point from which a lower beam hangs and the `+` on the lower beam indicates the point at which it balances. Your input does not need to include the `|`s if you don't need them. Lower beams with a width of 1 balance by default of course. The balancing of the top beam has to take the total weight of each lower beam into account.

As you can see, for each example, there are two positions marked `A` and `B` where I have forgotten whether they should be an `X` or a `Y`.

Please write a program a function which will accept the above diagram as input and output which of `X` and `Y` belong in each of the two positions `A` and `B`.

Your output should be something along the lines of `A=X, B=X` although any unambiguous output suffices e.g. you could output the diagram with the `A` and `B` substituted accordingly or you could modify the input in-place. You do not have to output values for `X` or `Y`, although for each diagram they always have a fixed ratio which will allow all beams to balance.

Other input formats could be acceptable but they need to get suggested as comments to the sandbox post.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 1):

[Posted: Prime Power Switch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210437/prime-power-switch)

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

#### Sandbox Question

Do people think this is worth posting, given it only really requires a prime check along with getting digit prefixes? There are multiple implementations (possibly including hard-coding in some languages) to consider which might be enough. Please vote!

---

Produce all 83 base-ten right-truncatable primes in as few bytes as possible in the language of your choice.

- Order is irrelevant, but the production **must** terminate.
- You may produce a list, a set, or an equivalent object.
- You may print them (e.g. space-separated, each on a line, or formatted as a list or set (e.g. `{2; 3; 293; 5; ...}`)
- You may give the numbers themselves as strings.
- You may produce an iterator (but evaluating it must terminate).

#### Right truncatable primes

A right truncatable prime is a prime for which removing any number of trailing decimal digits is also prime.
For example, \$7193\$ is a right truncatable prime since \$719\$, \$71\$, and \$7\$ are all prime.

There are only 83 such numbers in base-ten, when sorted they are:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 71, 73, 79, 233, 239, 293, 311, 313, 317, 373, 379, 593, 599, 719, 733, 739, 797, 2333, 2339, 2393, 2399, 2939, 3119, 3137, 3733, 3739, 3793, 3797, 5939, 7193, 7331, 7333, 7393, 23333, 23339, 23399, 23993, 29399, 31193, 31379, 37337, 37339, 37397, 59393, 59399, 71933, 73331, 73939, 233993, 239933, 293999, 373379, 373393, 593933, 593993, 719333, 739391, 739393, 739397, 739399, 2339933, 2399333, 2939999, 3733799, 5939333, 7393913, 7393931, 7393933, 23399339, 29399999, 37337999, 59393339, 73939133]
```

This is [A024770](https://oeis.org/A024770) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

---

For some mathematician-written* Python see https://youtu.be/f2lEB4nMmyI.
* Fair warning, it might well make you cringe.

Comment: I don't really mind prime challenges, just that most people who have been here a while have a stigma against it. [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89907/right-and-tfel-truncatable-primes)

Comment: The code in the link contains what appears to be a partially censored racial slur, so I think you should probably drop the youtube reference.

Comment: Otherwise I think this is probably interesting enough, as these primes have several other non-prime features. It might be problematic if too many answers are just primality checks wrapped in terminating loops, though?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Oh wow, I didn't notice; that's pretty sad.

Answer (score 1):

[Posted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211292/sporeball-numbers)

Comment: "one or more of the options for the longest palindromic run of digits in its binary representation can be removed" Does this mean I can remove several runs? For example, 945770 = 11100110111001101010_2 has 110011 as the longest palindromic run, it occurs twice and if I remove both occurrences, the result is 10101010. On the other hand, 944522 = 11100110100110001010_2 has 110011 and 001100 as longest palindromic runs, and removing both gives 10101010.

Comment: Don't forget [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57719/generate-dennis-numbers), [Dennis 2.0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94961/dennis-numbers-2-0) or [Calvin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57882/is-this-a-candidate-calvin-number) numbers :P

Comment: @Zgarb No; you should only remove a single run before splitting the remaining digits. I've clarified this in the challenge text.

Answer (score 1):

## Move the Knight!

Your knight is on `(0, 0)` on an infinite (to all of the four edges, not just two) chessboard, and you need to move it to `(a, b)`. You can use arbitrary (but finite) number of moves to do that. Since the chessboard is infinite, you can use squares with negative coordinates.

Since you only have 2 knights (if no promotion occured) to type the program, your program needs to be as short as possible.

### Input

The input is two integers, a and b.

### Output

You output a sequence of characters, each represents a move. There are eight directions to move, so your output should contain eight distinct characters, each represents one direction. They can be any eight characters, as long as they are all unique.

### Test Cases

The characters used here is:

```
 A B
C   D
  N
E   F
 G H
```

```
0 0 -> ""
1 1 -> "GD" or "DEGD" or "DG" etc.
3 3 -> "DDDGGG" (one possible version)
2 3 -> "FGD"
```

### Rules

- Standard Loopholes are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: @Razetime I did... "They can be any eight characters, as long as they are all unique."

Comment: oh, sorry about that.

Comment: @Razetime I intend to make this challenge have many different, unique, interesting approach, and which one is shorter highly depends on the language.

Answer (score 1):

## Do my data follow Benford's law or a uniform distibution?

### Background

Benford's law, also known as the law of anomalous numbers, describes the distribution of the leading digit in many numerical data sets. Let \$X\$ be the leading digit of an observation (in base 10). According to Benford's law, \$P[X=i]=\log_{10}(1+\frac1i)\$ for \$i=1\ldots 9\$.

For instance take the yearly reputation change of the top 1000 users on CGCC. For a user with reputation change 3522, keep only the leading digit, 3. Repeat this for all users, and you get this distribution, which is far from uniform:

[image]

This has been shown to apply to vary different data sets, from town populations to stock prices, and is used to detect tax and election fraud.

On the other hand, for some other data sets, the distribution of the leading digit is a uniform distribution: \$P[X=i] = \frac19\$ for \$i=1\ldots 9\$.

Given some observed frequencies \$(f_i)_{i=1\ldots 9}\$, we shall measure the distance to these two distributions using the sum of the errors in absolute value: \$\sum_i \left|f_i-\log_{10}(1+\frac1i)\right|\$ and \$\sum_i\left|f_i-\frac19\right|\$, respectively.

### Task

Take as input a list of non-zero numbers. For each number, keep only the leading digit, which is defined as the first non-zero digit. Compute the observed frequencies of leading digits, and output one of two values, depending on whether the observed frequencies are closer to Benford's law or to a uniform distribution.

### Input

Input format is flexible. Note that input may include negative values, as well as non-integers.

### Output

Either two consistent values, one for Benford's law and one for the uniform, or a truthy/falsey value.

### Test cases

To be added

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Answer (score 1):

## Finding the densest crossword puzzles

I love crosswords, and nothing beats a super densely packed puzzle. But how dense can the puzzles get?

Here's a sample puzzle I made a few years ago:

[image]

Certainly not great, but can we do better?

Given any list of characters, a crosswordification of that list is a crossword puzzle consisting of characters from that list. For example, given the list ['b','a','d','a','d'], the following is a valid crosswordification:

[image]

but this isn't

[image]

Clearly, the order of the list is irrelevant.

Given a valid crossword, the area of the crossword is the area of the smallest rectangle containing the crossword. In the above examples, the smallest rectangle containing the crosswords are 3x3 squares, which have area 9.

## Challenge

In this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, you must write a function which takes two arguments

- A list-like structure containing english characters
- A list-like of valid words consisting of english characters

and outputs an integer, representing the minimal area of a crosswordification of the list of english characters, where the second input defines the set of valid words.

I will be using [this](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) english dictionary for my test cases. Any code that is used to import/parse the dictionary into a list-like structure won't be counted in the byte-count, just the function.

## Test Cases

More to be added:

```
['d','a','a','a','t','n','m'] -> 7 (adamant is a word)

['k','a','s','a'] -> 6
```

Comment: Here's what I understand: Our programs need to calculate the smallest possible corssword from the given characters, display the size alone. correct?

Comment: @Razetime correct

Comment: Do you suspect there is any other way to do this apart from brute forcing all possible arrangements and picking the minimal area one that meets the requirements?

Comment: @Sisyphus yes, but not revealing, as thats part of the challenge

Answer (score 1):

## TPK Algorithm

The [TPK Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPK_algorithm) was designed in 1977 Donald Knuth and Luis Trabb Pardo to show off the various functionality of languages at the time. Your task is to implement the most common version of the TPK algorithm. The pseudocode goes as follows (adapted from Wikipedia):

```
ask for 11 numbers to be read into a sequence S
reverse sequence S
for each item N in sequence S
    call function F on N
    if the result is greater than 400
        print "TOO LARGE"
    else
        print result

F(N) results in sqrt(abs(N)) + 5 * pow(N,3)
```

`F` should be implemented as a function in your code, that is, there should be some subsection of you code which consists of a function that takes an input and outputs the result of F for that input. It is acceptable to round the square root operation down to the nearest integer.

Notes: if using decimal square roots, the first value greater than 400 is ~4.301. For integer square roots, the first value is ~4.302. Your program does not need to support non-integer inputs.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

Answer (score 1):

## C Code Compressor (WIP)

[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Your task is to create a lossless compression scheme that is optimized for ASCII-only C code. Whitespace and indentation should be preserved.

Your score is the total compressed size of various samples from well known open source C projects. A sample of the largest few files will be taken from one specific commit. Both header files and source files will be included from the following projects:

- The CPython Interpreter
- The Linux Kernel
- Git

Comments will be stripped from the source files for the set of scoring, therefore you do not need to optimize for comments, however you still need to handle them.

Three additional files will also be included in the corpus, which must be handled correctly, but do not contribute to your score:

- A C source file with comments
- A Python source file
- A non-programming plain text file (probably a short story or poem from the public domain. Jabberwocky?)

### Scoring

$$
Score = {C + D + L^2 \over O}
$$

Where:

- \$C\$ is the total size, in bytes, of the compressed text
- \$O\$ is the total size, in bytes, of the original text
- \$D\$ is the total length, in bytes, of all strings in any predefined dictionary
- \$L\$ is the length, in bytes, of the longest string in any predefined dictionary

Lowest score wins

#### Predefined Dictionaries

(Needs refinement)

A predefined dictionary, for the purposes of this challenge, is a collection of predefined output strings of length 2 or greater which are baked into your encoding format.

- An entry in a predefined dictionary must have at least two different characters to be counted in scoring, so repeating a single character \$n\$ times does not count as a dictionary entry.
- Leading and trailing whitespace on a predefined string does not count as a distinct entry from one without matching leading or trailing whitespace

A predefined dictionary may, for instance, be helpful for keywords and common identifiers, but it is ultimately up to you what approach you take.

For instance, if you map `\x80` to `int` and `\x81` to `float`, your dictionary score would be \$8\$ for the total length, plus \$25\$ for the longest string (`float`), for a total of \$33\$. However, mapping runs of tabs and spaces to `\xC0`-`\xFF` would not count toward dictionary size in this case.

### Rules

- Standard rules and loopholes apply.
- Although scoring only depends on how well you can compress C, your algorithm needs to work even when the input text is not valid C; it must work for all ASCII input text.
- Your algorithm must be deterministic, meaning it should always produce the same compressed text every time for any given input, regardless of external factors such as time.

Comment: Once you reveal the test cases, couldn’t I just create an “encoding” where 1 represents the Linux kernel, 2 represents the Git source, etc? And if the test cases aren’t fixed but can change if an answer overfits some, then is there really an objective winning criterion?

Comment: @water_ghosts Optimizing exclusively for the test cases given [is one of the standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507)

Comment: Are you planning on scoring based entirely on compression amount, or also on code size? Seems like it will be a fun challenge, especially is code size is part of it.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've done a compression challenge before and I found that making code size a part of the score got in the way of making things interesting since it typically encouraged calling out to gzip since that takes way fewer bytes than making an actual algorithm. I might consider a code size limitation or work in dictionary size into score though.

Answer (score 1):

## Three points on Poincaré disk

### What is Poincaré disk?

Poincaré disk is a projection of 2-dimensional [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) to the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane, or more precisely, onto the open disk \$\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1^2\}\$.

### Objective

It is well-known that three **distinct** points on the Euclidean plane are either on a unique line or on a unique circle. Let \$S\$ be that line/circle.

The inverse image of \$S\$ is one of **line**, **circle**, **horocycle**, or **hypercycle**. Determine which.

### Classification

The points are assumed to be on the disk.

- If \$S\$ is a circle that lies on the disk, the inverse image is a **circle**.
- Otherwise, if \$S\$ is a circle that shares a tangent with the boundary of the disk, the inverse image is a **horocycle**.
- Otherwise, if \$S\$ crosses the boundary of the disk orthogonally, the inverse image is a **line**.
- Otherwise, the inverse image is a **hypercycle**.

### Input

The cartesian 2-dimensional coordinates of the points. A coordinate can be given as either two real numbers or one complex number. Other than that, the input type and format doesn't matter. This includes:

- A tuple of size 3
- A list of size 3
- A set of size 3

Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation. This includes:

- Not exactly 3 points
- Non-distinct points
- A point not on the disk

### Output

Output type and format doesn't matter either. This includes:

- Enumeration type of 4 possible values
- Bit field of size 2

### Example

Assuming there were no floating-point errors:

- \$\{(-½,0),(0,½),(½,0)\}\$ must give a **circle**.
- \$\{(-½,½),(0,0),(½,½)\}\$ must give a **horocycle**.
- \$\{(-½,0),(0,0),(½,0)\}\$ must give a **line**.
- \$\{(1-\sqrt{¾},½),(1-\sqrt{½},1-\sqrt{½}),(½,1-\sqrt{¾})\}\$ must also give a **line**.
- \$\{(0,½),(¼,¼),(½,0)\}\$ must give a **hypercycle**.
- \$\{(0,0),(¾,0),(0,¾)\}\$ must also give a **hypercycle**.

Comment: Can the coordinates \$(x,y)\$ be represented as a complex number \$x+yi\$?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes.

Comment: It looks like solutions might have trouble with the line and horocycle cases due to float precision, if either they take values like `sqrt(2)` to finite precision or introduce imprecisions in the calculations. Can some allowance be made for this? I'm not sure how though.

Comment: @xnor If the input is IEEE floating-point numbers, they are in \$\mathbb{Z}[½]\$ anyway and must be regarded as such. If your language is able to do symbolic computation, you may go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

## Compactify the real numbers to a group (WIP)

### Objective

Let \$X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}\$. The \$\infty\$ is the **point at infinity** and doesn't have a signature.

Let \$Y = \{\exp(i\theta) : \theta \in [0,2\pi)\}\$, which is the **unit circle** on the complex plane.

Make \$X\$ a group by giving \$X\$ a binary operation, so there will exist a function \$f : X → Y\$ that is both an **isomorphism** and a **homeomorphism**.

Your code shall implement the binary operation. \$f\$ doesn't need to be implemented to a code.

### Group

A set \$G\$ endowed with a binary operation \$*\$ is a **group** iff:

- For every \$a,b,c \in G\$, \$(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)\$
- There exists the **identity element** \$e \in G\$ such that for every \$a \in G\$, \$e * a = a * e = a\$
- For every \$a \in G\$, there exists \$b \in G\$ such that \$b * a = a * b = e\$

\$Y\$ is a group, where the binary operation is the multiplication.

### Isomorphism

Let \$*\$ denote the binary operation given to \$X\$.

A function \$f : X → Y\$ is an **isomorphism** iff:

- \$f\$ is bijective
- For every \$x,y \in X\$, \$f(x*y) = f(x) × f(y)\$

Note that once appropriate \$f\$ is identified, \$*\$ can be automatically defined as \$x * y = f^{-1}(f(x) × f(y))\$.

### Topology

A subset \$A \subset X\$ is **open** iff, for every \$x \in A\$:

- If \$x \in \mathbb{R}\$, there exists \$P \subset A\$ such that \$x \in P\$ and \$P\$ is an open interval
- If \$x = \infty\$, there exists a subset \$P \subset A\$ such that \$x \in P\$ and \$P\$ is the union of two open rays to the opposite directions

A subset \$B \subset Y\$ is **open** iff, for every \$y \in B\$, there exists a subset \$Q \subset B\$ such that \$y \in Q\$ and \$Q\$ is an open arc.

### Homeomorphism

A function \$f : X → Y\$ is a **homeomorphism** iff:

- \$f\$ is bijective
- For every open subset \$A \subset X\$, its **image** \$f[A]\$ is open in \$Y\$.
- For every open subset \$B \subset Y\$, its **inverse image** \$f^{-1}[B]\$ is open in \$X\$.

### Rule

You may represent \$\mathbb{R}\$ as a floating-point number. Every floating-point error will be tolerated in this regard.

### Example

An example of \$f\$ is:

$$
f(x) = \exp(i × 2 \arctan \frac{x}{2})
$$

where \$\arctan \infty = \frac{\pi}{2}\$, and we identify \$*\$ as:

$$
x * y = 2 × \tan (\arctan \frac{x}{2} + \arctan \frac{y}{2})
$$

where the identity element is \$0\$, and the inverse element of \$x\$ is \$-x\$ when \$x \in \mathbb{R}\$, or \$\infty\$ if \$x = \infty\$.

### Ungolfed solution

#### Haskell

This implementation abuses the fact that IEEE floating-point numbers can encode infinities. Both positive infinity and negative infinity will be treated the same in this regard.

```
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Group

newtype CompactR = CompactR Double deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Semigroup CompactR where
    CompactR x <> CompactR y = CompactR $ 2 * tan (atan (x/2) + atan (y/2))

instance Monoid CompactR where
    mempty = CompactR 0

instance Group CompactR where
    invert (CompactR x) = CompactR (negate x)
```

You implement only `<>`. The others are just details.

## Sandbox questions

This challange turned out to be too easy.

What if I asked about one-point compactification of \$\mathbb{C}\$ instead of \$\mathbb{R}\$?

Comment: I think even just `f(x,y)=(x+y)/(1+xy)` works for the real case

Answer (score 1):

## (Pan)consummate Vs

An integer \$v\$ is said to be *consummate* if there is an integer \$n\$ and a base \$b\$ such that \$n\$ divided by the sum of its base \$b\$ digits is equal to \$v\$.

An integer \$v\$ is said to be *panconsummate* if it is consummate in all bases \$b\geq 2\$. Panconsummate numbers are [A058226](http://oeis.org/A058226) in the OEIS.

### Your task:

Write a full program or function that takes a positive integer \$v\$ and returns two distinct, consistent values, one if \$v\$ is panconsummate, and the other if \$v\$ is not. However, **the sum of your code's bytes must be panconsummate as well**. Your code must work theoretically for any integer.

Truthy values:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 31, 34, 36, 37, 39, 40, 43, 45, 53, 54, 57, 59, 61, 69, 72, 73, 77, 78, 81, 85, 89, 91, 121, 127, 144, 166, 169, 211, 219, 231, 239, 257, 267, 271, 331, 337, 353, 361, 413, 481, 523, 571, 661, 721, 1093, 1291, 3097
```

Falsey values:

```
13, 16, 17, 19, 22, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 38, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 56, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 74, 75, 76, 79, 80, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 90, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 167, 168, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200
```

Note that panconsummate numbers \$v>3097\$ must be at least \$10^6\$, and the OEIS speculates that the truthy values above are all panconsummate numbers.

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

Answer (score 1):

## Convert hexadecimal to decimal

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

We have a lot of base conversion challenges. Surprisingly, aside from one [closed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/hexadecimal-to-decimal) challenge, there aren't any where the goal is purely to convert hexadecimal to decimal. This is different from challenges like converting hexadecimal to binary, because many languages have features like hexadecimal literals (`0x`, `$`, etc.) which can do this in a much shorter or more interesting way.

**I/O:**

You should create either a program or function, which takes input and output through one of the allowed methods. The input will be a hexadecimal number, consisting of the characters `/[0-9a-f]/` (you may choose the capitalization rules).

**Scoring:**

This is code golf, shortest answer per language wins.

Comment: Feedback is of course useful. If the downvote is because this is a dupe or is unnecessary, that would be useful to comment on. Otherwise, I can't fix any issues without knowing what they are.

Answer (score 1):

## Is a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices closest to the origin? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I've deleted from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213881/85527) because I agree it is takes too much time to understand at the moment.

### Preface

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question where the technique must *search or exclude from search* all possibilities. As soon as I figure out how to pose it, there will be a separate [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) question for mathematical techniques other than a simple search, so please don't use them here.

Below is quoted from Math SE [determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619):

> A pair of hexagonal lattices with one scaled by the square root of a rational number \$r = \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}\$ and then rotated will produce a variety of different hexagonal lattices of coincident points.
>
> For the first lattice let
>
> $$x, y = i+\frac{1}{2}j, \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}j$$
>
> and for the second
>
> $$x, y = r\left(k+\frac{1}{2}l\right), \ r\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}l\right).$$
>
> Per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669744/284619) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327186/284619) helpful answer the squares of the distances to unit lattice points are given by [Loeschian numbers (A003136)](http://oeis.org/A003136) equal to \$i^2+ij+j^2\$ so in this case a point \$i, j\$ on the first lattice will coincide with a point \$k, l\$ on the second lattice once rotated by some amount if
>
> $$n(i^2+ij+j^2) = m(k^2+kl+l^2).$$
>
> For example if \$m, n = 13, 7\$ then both \$(i, j) = (5, 6)\$ and \$(6, 5)\$ will coincide with \$(k, l) = (5, 3)\$ at rotation angles of about 5.2 and 11.2 degrees as given by.
>
> $$\theta = \arctan\left( \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}l}{k+\frac{1}{2}l} \right) - \arctan\left( \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}j}{i+\frac{1}{2}j} \right)$$
>
> However, while the first solution is part of the hexagonal superlattice built on the much closer point \$(i, j), (k, l) = (1, 3), (1, 2)\$ the second point represents the shortest possible coincident distance *and therefore a far lower density coincident lattice*.
>
> [image: coincident hexagonal lattices]
>
> plotting script: https://pastebin.com/pZFCGXbE

### Task

Given the rational number (m, n) e.g. (13, 7) and pairs of known coincident lattice points, e.g. (5, 6), (3, 5) or (6, 5), (3, 5) (besides the origin) we want to find out if this is one of the six closest coincident lattice points, or if it is a member of a coincident lattice with points closer.

- **If it's one of the six closest:** return some flag letting us know there wasn't anything closer. You may also return either the same point, or one of the other five of identical distance.
- **If it isn't:** return one of the six points that was closest along with (but not only) a flag letting us know that a closer point was found and the original point wasn't one of the closest. Reminder that this will be a closer point in a coincident lattice that also contains the original input.

Do this by some combination of searching/testing all possible pairs of lattice points (one from each lattice) to see if they are coincident and closer and potentially excluding blocks of combinations that don't need searching. The problem is finite because one only searches points that aren't obviously farther from the origin.

Feel free to use tricks to exclude large fractions from search as long as they rely on simple rules, for example a point near the origin in one lattice will never be coincident with a point near a distant point in the other.

But if you find yourself considering computations like matrix division or using [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) or [Euclid's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829536/284619) in the complex plane please save that for the follow-up [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) question.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

### Input

- Input will have six integers \$(m, n), (i, j), (k, l)\$ as described above, but can have any order or hierarchy, or additional (but uninformative) place holders (e.g. zero padding, blanks...)
- \$(m, n)\$ will be positive, but the other four can be positive, negative or zero, excluding a \$(0, 0)\$ pair (the origin).

### Recipe for making test cases

In addition to the two mentioned above (13, 7), (5, 6), (5, 3) and (13, 7), (6, 5), (5, 3) you can roll your own:

1. Pick two Loeschian numbers \$L_1\$ and \$L_2\$ and find some integer pairs (i, j), (k, l) that can make them. ([Find all integer pairs that produce a given Loeschian number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212300/85527))
2. Make new pairs by choosing two nonzero integers \$a, b\$, then:

\begin{align}
i' & = ai - bj\\
j' & = aj + b(i+j)\\
k' & = ak - bl\\
l' & = al + b(k+l).
\end{align}

If \$i, j\$  and \$k, l\$ were coincident, then  \$i', j'\$  and \$k', l'\$ will be as well.

(This just says that the coincidence lattice between two hexagonal lattices is also a hexagonal lattice.)

Answer (score 1):

## Get the Systematic Chemical Symbol

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214044/get-the-systematic-chemical-symbol)

Comment: "prints the corresponding chemical symbol." → "prints the corresponding systematic chemical symbol."

Comment: You should state clearly that taking a list of digits is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As a Web Frontend developer, I feel out of place most of the time coming here. And that is despite the existence of established challenges like [One Div](https://a.singlediv.com/) in the field of web development. But they aren't here, because objective criteria are hard to do. (Sparing more unkind reasons.)

Maybe the following would be a way to draw others. It's not a One Div challenge, but a way to set different web technologies against one another in a sort of code golf.

To give you an idea, compare these two Codepens:

- https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gOMOMYz 4 lines of Pug and 28 lines of SCSS
- https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/jOrMjLW 19 lines of Pug and 8 lines of Sass

(To be fair, `thebabydino` doesn't know at the time of writing there is a challenge, it was a [spontaneous idea](https://css-tricks.com/smarter-ways-to-generate-a-deep-nested-html-structure/#comment-1764284) after seeing her code.)

It was rightly pointed out to me that capturing the idea of good coding practice will probably fail. But let me give you a vision: **What if the challenges were not only about learning new coding tricks, but also about identifying the "cheats"?**

There is a whole industry out there that tries to make objective rules to ultimately measure code quality. Their work is mostly to tilt against windmills. Maybe there is a way to make a playfull challenge a tool to identify new features for linters.

If good coding wins, so much better for it. If everyone thinks the winner was going squarely against the spirit of good coding practice, professionalism gains a discussion.

(Somehow this reminds me of the discussion about doping in sports.)

*I hope to make the playing field understandable also to non-web people, so please bear with me if I add comments that would be obvious to everyone in the profession.*

One goal here is performance. There are a lot of champions for the approach to minimize external dependencies loaded into the browser. I am trying to capture this with a "no external request" rule. This is not only about the size of files loaded but also the debt of interpreting extensive JS frameworks. Look at current discussions about web site performance, and you will understand what I am talking about.

### Challenge: Recreate the image with web technologies

A real question would contain a raster image in any format. Most likely, they will be PNG or GIF (to show animations).

#### The code must be runnable on [Codepen](https://codepen.io)

You must create a pen and post its URL here. Your own authorship should be on a honors base. Anonymous pens are acceptable, but if your nick is the same here as there, you must use your account.

> There are a good number of web development environments around, but they all offer different features. The criterium for selection was the ease to enforce the "no external resources" rule - and popularity, of course.

In addition, the code must be posted in its entirety here.

#### No external code

The pen must not include any external sources.

- No import statements in any language
- no statements that trigger any external requests
- no external stylesheets or scripts imported via the pen settings

> An important case here is the use of JS frameworks that offer server-side rendering, or template languages like JSX. Should their source code be made legal? This sort of code is mostly undistinguishable from code used client-side, with the difference that it must be compiled before it is delivered to the client.

#### No base64-encoding

No part of the code should be unreadable at first glance. So neither HTML, nor CSS, nor JS are allowed to contain any base64-encoded strings

- No `data:` URI that contains the `base64` option
- The use of `atob()` and `btoa()` in JS is ok, provided there is no string literal containing a base64-encoded string
- The use of `<canvas>` and/or `URL.createObjectURL()` is certainly ok, provided there is no string literal containing a base64-encoded string
- The use of `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` to construct images is certainly ok.

#### The use of preprocessors is allowed

Any preprocessor that is offered by CodePen can be used. What counts for the solution is the source code in that language.

Using Babel as a preprocessor inside CodePen is ok, but the "no imports" rule applies just the same.

> Currently the Babel preprocessor offered by CodePen has a fixed configuration. If that changes in the future, it might be valid or not to use an URI to an external config file or npm module or not. That is in the future. The basic idea here is *"if it is executed on the server side, or by native browser code, go for it"*

#### Linting must pass

To give languages a fair chance that rely on fixed indents, and to maintain readability, the Javascript part must pass [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) without any warning or error.

> 1. Which preset does the best to enforce good code quality? It was pointed out that there will probably remain a number of loopholes, but I would like to try to get them as few and obscure as possible.
> 2. I am not so fluent with linters for other languages. Proposals?

#### No minification

All code should be pretty.

- Running [`prettier`](https://prettier.io) must not change the code formatting

  > This might not cover all languages. Please review and propose other/additional formatters.
- No code line can be longer than 80 columns

#### Matching the source image

> I have still to research that. My first instinct is to use ImageMagicks `magick compare` and set a cutoff value to account for antialiasing and rounding differences, but that does not solve how to capture animations. Maybe capture all frames with Lighthouse?

#### Wining criterium: aggregated Number of lines of code

The number of lines of source code in markup, stylesheet and script are added. The least number of lines wins.

- Numbers are counted using [sloc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc). Only the `Source` output value is relevant. For example on the command line

  ```
    sloc pen.css | grep Source
  ```

  > is there a sensible way to scrape the code lines directly from Codepen? Or is this available on the site and I am simply not aware of it?

Please give your answer a header that qoutes the number of lines in each language separately.

Comment: While giving 'languages a fair chance' by enforcing no base64 and counting lines of code only is admirable, I think you will find that there are too many ways to cheese it. For example, I could write every line as `eval('...' + '...' + '...')` to escape minification. It might be better just to use a more conventional scoring criteria (bytes) and drop the base64/formatting requirements.

Comment: I am not giving up on this so easily. If there is to be a challenge, it should be on the basis that is done with good coding practice. Otherwise, it just makes no sense. Linters should be able to catch a lot of the loopholes, and if not, at least this would be a way for others to learn about them. Isn't this also the goal of this community? My vision would be that if this gains popularity, Linter manufactureres look at "cheating" solutions for improvements to their product.

Comment: @ccprog Unfortunately, "good coding practice" is a subjective thing, and we strive for objective scoring criteria. Most answers on the site will happily sacrifice things such as readability and good practice in order to reduce their score.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Did you see my latest edit? Maybe this can be a productive goal in itself.

Comment: @ccprog I was mainly responding to your comment, I was still reading through the full spec as I wrote that. I do very much like the idea of this challenge, and I think it should be fully able to do while still fitting within our site rules (objective scoring criteria etc.). I'm not too familiar with the topic of web technologies, so forgive any mistakes I may make, but one thing sticks out to me as needing improvement when reading this challenge: the attempts to cover things in all languages. Usually, we tend to avoid language-specific challenges on the site, but I think this would be a (cont)

Comment: (cont) good example of where limiting the language would help rather than harm the challenge. From my understanding, it looks as though restricting answers to Javascript would allow you to make the challenge much more objective with the rules about minification and base64, as you won't have to worry about edge cases in esoteric languages such as Jelly or ><> that are commonly used on the site.

Comment: That, on the other hand is unrealistic. Most Javascript code nowadays is somehow cross-compiled, either from other languages (for example the Typescript superset) or through the use of frameworks (Angular, React). I'll have to think more about th "no imports" rule here, as one of the banes of current web development is that a lot of devs loose the sight of whether their code is executed server or client side.

Comment: As far as esoteric languages are concerned, there is an implicit stop gag: Forcing Codepen as execution environment. If the language isn't supported there,, the answer fails. And believe me, Codepen is an industry tool, not just any website. Every post there is considered to be a showcase for the developer and counts for his/her professional reputation.

Comment: @ccprog I actually have no problem with the challenge as specified. I just think that the winning solutions will cheat the tool(s) you use to score. But if that's ok with you, I don't mind this challenge at all, and will look forward to see the answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Is It A Rainbow Color

[Posted in main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214678/is-it-a-rainbow-color)

Comment: "obviously not an index" isn't so clear. Is 7 "obviously not an index" if we use 0-based indexing?

Comment: Adding to that: In some languages, `-1` and `false` are valid indices.

Comment: Ok updated it to make it a bit more definitive.

Comment: Doesn't this give an unfair advantage to languages that use `-1` for "not found" when asking for an index? Other languages give the next index after the last valid index.

Comment: What would you suggest then? I feel no matter what, there's always going to be some languages that are better suited to a particular challenge. I tried to offer as many ways as possible for handling invalid input to be more language-inclusive.

Comment: Well, let's take a step back and look at the essence of the challenge. There are [two things](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319): a look-up, and the compression of the words. I'd focus on one, i.e. either let "not found" have undefined behavior, or simply be a cover for look-up (given a list and a value, find the index, or … if not found). Since the latter is probably too boring, go with the simple lookup.

Comment: I strongly recommend removing the invalid-input case and just guaranteeing that the input is valid. It means answers don't have to store all valid inputs in some form to check against them, which gives rooms for more interesting methods of fingerprinting.

Comment: I feel like we've already have some challenge(s) about mapping a set of n strings to the numbers 1 through n, though I don't quite remember what they were or how to find them. The concept is a good one, but it may have been done already.

Comment: This is some valuable feedback. I agree that we've had some very similar challenges, how would it work if I rework the challenge to be something along the lines of this: output whether a given color is in the rainbow. The possible inputs would be pre-defined and output can be truthy/falsy

Comment: I can't help thinking this will boil down to a "let xnor find some magic trick that simplifies it significantly and then adapt it to every other programming language" challenge

Comment: I think this actually should have good variety across languages. It's string-based, and different languages have various abilities to use regexes, hashes, conversion to code points, etc, that differ in relative length. This is in contrast to purely arithmetic ones where a single formula can be ported easily.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix the message on my calculator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

My calculator has lots of mathematical buttons, but they're boring; it's much more fun to write messages using letters. You can access the letters of the alphabet with the <kbd>ALPHA</kbd> button which turns each button press into a corresponding letter which is noted above each key (or space, in the case of <kbd>.</kbd>).

My calculator looks like this*:

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F
log   ln   ^2  sin  cos  tan
-----------------------------
 G    H    I    J    K    L
 /    ->   (    )    ,   Esc
-----------------------------
 M     N     O
 7     8     9 
-----------------------------
 P     Q     R     S     T
 4     5     6     *     %
-----------------------------
 U     V     W     X     Y
 1     2     3     +     -
-----------------------------
 Z    (Space)
 0       .
```

For example, to type `HELLO` I would press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>cos</kbd> <kbd>-></kbd> <kbd>-></kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>.

However, recently my <kbd>ALPHA</kbd> button was broken, so I can't get to the letters any more. When I try to write a message, only the mathematical symbols get input.

Without ALPHA, the keys do the following:

- The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key does nothing
- The digit keys, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>-></kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, and <kbd>%</kbd> enter those strings verbatim
- The <kbd>log</kbd>, <kbd>ln</kbd>, <kbd>sin</kbd>, <kbd>cos</kbd>, and <kbd>tan</kbd> keys enter `function_name()` and place the cursor before the closing bracket
- The <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>^2</kbd> keys enter a `/` or `^2` respectively, and then move the cursor to before the new symbol, iff the symbol preceding it is one of `+ - * % ( , ->`

For the example above, instead of getting the message `HELLO`, I would get `->cos(9)`. Note that since the key for L (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) does nothing, it is unfortunately impossible to know that the letter L was pressed, and this information is lost.

Your task is to convert a string of maths operations into the correct text.

### Rules

- Some combinations are ambiguous; for example `CGI`, `CIG`, `ICG` all could have come from `(/^2`. In this case you can output any or all of them.
- You should assume the input will always be a valid combination that could have been produced using the rules above.
- You should never output `L`s
- You may output the string in any case, with an optional trailing newline, but no other extra whitespace.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest code in bytes wins.
- Standard rules and loopholes apply.

### Test-cases

More coming soon.

```
      Input                 Output
----------------------------------------
789                    MNO
log(ln(^2))            ABC
cos((cos((9)           EIEIO
-->-                   YHY
3.14159                W UPUQO
(/^2                   CGI or CIG or ICG
<empty string>         <empty string>
```

<sub>* The `%` and `/` keys are both for division on the original calculator, but labelled something like `÷` and `☐/☐`. Here I've just replaced them with simple ASCII equivalents. (did you know that both `%` and `÷` represent a fraction?) Also, there are other keys not shown (including the mentioned <kbd>ALPHA</kbd>), but they don't matter for this challenge.</sub>

---

## Meta

- Any feedback or suggestions?
- Is this clear enough?
- I considered adding some regular expressions to show more clearly what the rules mean, but decided not to because I though that should be part of the challenge. Was this the right decision?
- I will probably make another challenge that is the reverse of this - given a list of buttons that were pressed, produce the correct mathematical symbols. It might have made sense to post that challenge first as context for this one, but I thought this one is more interesting
- Regarding ambiguity: I could change some of the syntax rules to reduce the ambiguity but it would make things a lot more complicated and it couldn't be removed completely without straying significantly from the behaviour of the original calculator

Answer (score 1):

## Set of subsets without subsubsets

You are given two integers \$n\$ and \$k\$, and are to output a random collection of \$k\$ sets \$\mathcal A_1,\ldots,\mathcal A_k\$ such that:

- each \$\mathcal A_i\$ is a subset of \$\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}\$;
- no \$\mathcal A_i\$ is a subset of another \$\mathcal A_j\$.

Any collection which satisfies these constraints should have positive probability of being output.

Input/output is flexible.

You may assume that there exists at least one collection which satisfies the constraint; by [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem), this is equivalent to the condition \$k\leq \tbinom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\$.

#### Example outputs

The output is random, so these example collections should merely have positive probability of being output.

```
| n | k | possible output
| 2 | 2 | { {1}, {2} }
| 4 | 3 | { {1}, {2,3}, {3,4} }
| 4 | 6 | { {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,4} }
| 5 | 3 | { {1,2,3,4}, {2,5}, {3,5} }
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: What does random output do to benefit this challenge?  Randomness just adds boilerplate and prevents some languages from competing.  That doesn't make randomness bad universally, but it does suggest that there should be a reason you involve randomness.

Comment: @WheatWizard One alternative would be "output any collection of subsets which satisfies the constraints". But that challenge is trivial: it suffices to output `k` different subsets, all of size \$n\choose {n/2}\$; many challenges have a built-in for this. I included the randomness to sidestep this.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thinking about it, I now realize there is another alternative: list *all* acceptable collections of subsets, rather than a random collection. That seemed more tedious to me when I wrote the proposal, but it might actually be better; I'll think about it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

## The Slices Puzzle Puzzle

## Background

[Slices](https://slices.ovh/?puzzles) is a puzzle game. Placed on a 2d map is a set of islands; possibly just a single island. Placed on each island is a set of points. The task is to draw a number of **straight** lines across the islands such that no point can be reached from another without crossing one of the drawn lines, or leaving an island. In other words, you partition the points with lines such that each partition contains at most one point on each island. For each level, you are given a maximum number of lines that can be drawn.

In the game illustrated below, drawing a straight line between the first and second row of points, and then a line between the second and third row of points, would create a valid partition of points.

[image: Game illustration]

## Task

Your task is to write a solver for this game. The solver takes as input a set of islands, the set of points for each island plus the maximum number of lines which can be drawn. The input and output may be represented in any way, and the input may be hard-coded. Hard-coded input must show that your solution is sufficiently general. Any format will be accepted. For instance, you might implement this as a linear programme in the CPLEX format -- I haven't verified that this is possible -- or you might write some sort of brute force solution in in an imperative language. Maybe some other declarative solution works even more nicely.

## Grading

Solutions will be judged by popularity. Things such as number of bytes in the solution, computational complexity (justify this if you want) and elegance could be considered.

Comment: 1) Should the lines (separating the points) be straight lines? 2) Allowing hardcoded input is different from our I/O defaults, and may interfere with code golf scoring. 3) Complexity is often hard to measure, and elegance is not an objective winning criterion. My suggestion is pure [tag:code-golf], pure [tag:fastest-code], or *maybe* [tag:popularity-contest]. (For fastest code, you'll need to prepare some test cases, and get ready to run all submissions on your own machine. This is how we achieve objective scoring for speed.)

Comment: @Bubbler The lines should be straight. I would like to allow hard-coded inputs, as this makes it possible to submit a nice linear programme if that is possible. I think I will go for popularity given that there are so many interesting dimensions. I will update the question with this in mind.

Comment: @Bubbler What do you think about the task now?

Comment: Regardless of the challenge type, you need to provide *some* test cases for verifying submissions - at least a couple of easy levels and a couple of harder ones, maybe some that requires drawing lines at unexpected angles.

Comment: @Bubbler Will do.

Comment: Computational geometry problems have a lot of nuance. e.g are the points in general position, or can they be collinear? Can a cut just touch a vertex, or must it actually cross an edge? Is an island just the convex hull of its points, or is it given as a polygon? Are the convex hulls (resp. polygons) of the islands guaranteed to be mutually disjoint?

Comment: @user1502040 I will clarify these questions. I would like to make the representation of the solution as general as possible. Can you clarify what you mean by "Can a cut just touch a vertex, or must it actually cross an edge". By edge, do you mean edge of an island? Lines should not intersect with vertices. I should clarify that lines are not line segments, and that they should extend to infinity.

Comment: @justinpc Sorry, I can see how that was confusing. I meant the conceptual edge joining two points in the same island.

Comment: @justinpc I know most of your feedback has been discouraging, but I think this would be a fun challenge. Don't be nervous about posting it!

Comment: @user1502040 You're right. It would be a fun challenge. I have been busy recently, and would like to put time into this when I have a spare minute.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of strings like this (input):

`["some test", "{", "some", "_subst", "ring}", "some", "other text"]`

Need to combine all the elements in to one for the given substring (input).

For example:

`substring = "{some_substring}"`

The output list of strings will be

`["some text", "{some_substring}", "some other text" ]`

Here are few more possible lists of strings:

```
input_list = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list2 = ['some test', '{sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list3 = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list4 = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string', '}', 'som other text']
input_list5 = ['some test {', 'sub', 'string', '}', 'som other text']
input_list6 = ['some test {', 'sub', 'string', '} som other text']
```

`substring` can be any text and it does not need to be wrapped in to round braces. If `substring` appears multiple times in the input string than it should be replaced as well.

***Note*:** *Elements of the string that do not contain part of the input string should be the same instances.
So creating a new list from joned string will not work for this problem.*

*Let say these strings carry additional information like style. So removing or replacing them will remove style as well*

Signature of expected function to better understand problem.

```
def join_variable(input_list, substring):
    # implementation
    return output_list
```

Comment: You need to specify a winning criterion (usually [tag:code-golf])

Comment: Not exactly sure what do you mean. What kind of criterion? Can share some examples?

Comment: We don't host challenges where the goal is solve the problem. Rather, there must be a way to "score" solutions so they compete with each other. See [why](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria).

Comment: Got it. Alright then. Should I remove it?

Comment: You can use [tag:code-golf] as a scoring criterion, I think - shortest code wins. It's the most commonly used tag here.

Answer (score 1):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217511/does-this-javascript-function-support-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

## Win a K vs KQ endgame

### Summary

The goal of this challenge is to create a program or function which will win a Chess game with a King and Queen against a lone King. The user will specify three squares, representing the locations of the computer's King, the computer's Queen, and the user's King. The computer will then a output a move which will eventually lead to checkmate.

### Input/Output

The program or function will first take as input three squares, representing the locations of the computer's King, the computer's Queen, and the user's King (not necessarily in that order). It can be assumed that the input is a legal position.

Parsing input is not the point of this challenge, so all reasonable forms of input/output are allowed, including but not limited to

- Strings with algebraic chess notation such as `"Ke4"` or `"Qf6"`
- Triples representing pieces and coordinates such as `('K', 0, 2)`

After three squares are taken as input, the computer outputs a single legal move. Behaviour on invalid input is undefined.

### Requirements

This procedure must terminate using your program or function:

- User sets up a legal KQ vs K position on a physical chessboard.
- User inputs the board position. The computer outputs a legal move. If the move is a checkmate, STOP.
- User makes the computer's move on the physical board.
- User makes a legal move for the lone king on the physical board.
- User goes to step 2 and repeats.

In other words, the computer must eventually win by checkmate, through repeatedly using your program or function.

Furthermore, from any legal starting position the checkmate must occur in 50 or fewer moves by the computer.

(Of course, a physical chessboard is in no way necessary to test the code; I only mentioned it to help visualize the procedure. The chessboard could just as well be visualized in the user's head.)

### Possible test cases

The squares are given in the order: *computer's Queen, computer's King, user's King*

- `c2, h8, a1` (must avoid stalemate)
- `a1, a2, a8`
- `a8, a1, e5`

### Rules

- The checkmate must occur in 50 or fewer moves by the computer, but it does not need to be as fast as possible.
- Chess libraries are not permitted.
- Shortest program in each language (in bytes) wins.

### Questions for sandbox

How can I word the rules better if they are not currently sufficiently clear?

Comment: 'It can be assumed that the input is a legal position from which it is possible to force checkmate in 50 or fewer moves.' It's [always possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate#King_and_queen) to force checkmate in a KQ vs K endgame (when the side with the queen has the move) in 10 moves or fewer. I wonder if you should consider lowering the 50-move limit?

Comment: I don't want to lower the limit too much because it is conceivable that some good solutions might require more than 10 moves.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think you should mention that mating in 10 moves is always possible, even if you allow for more. Right now the question reads as if the possibility of forcing checkmate in 50 moves is an assumption (which it is not).

Comment: In a pedantic reading, 'The user will specify three squares' could be understood to mean that the same starting position (chosen by the user) is always used. Can you make it clearer that the program should work for any legal starting position (I assume this is what you intend)?

Comment: @Dingus The fact that any position can be won in 10 or fewer moves isn't really relevant to the specification of the challenge, but if you think it improves the prompt I'll go ahead and add it.

Comment: @Dingus I explain what I mean in the next section, and I'll be surprised if anyone reads this and thinks I meant to use the same starting position every time.

Comment: I agree that the 10 moves doesn't affect the spec. Where I see the possible relevance is as an answerer, where I might keep that knowledge in the back of my mind as a reference point to focus my golfing strategy. To your Sandbox questions: 1. I won't offer a strong opinion either way, just an observation: banning libraries will likely lead to fewer answers. Library-based answers might be boring but voters tend to vote accordingly. 2. I agree that there's no reason to specify which side is which.

Comment: @Dingus Thanks for your input.

Comment: Disallowing chess libraries sounds alright, since there's only 3 pieces to account for. [More complex problems](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216380/chess-murder-mystery/216406#216406) have been answered without libraries, but many tend to use libraries since it's simply golfier and simpler. I think this question would benefit from [tag:fastest-code] scoring, or something similar, rather than [tag:code-golf].

Comment: I think fastest code would be tricky to test due to the potentially numerous user inputs needed per code run, and testing how short of a mate the programs can find is not really what I had in mind for this challenge.

Comment: Just commenting since you requested, I think this is good.  My only real disagreement was the interactivity and since you have changed it and the spec remains clear, it has my thumbs up for as much as that is worth.

Answer (score 1):

## Map the alternating group A5 to the rotations of a dodecahedron

8 years ago, the Math Stack Exchange [was able](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130464/theorem-the-icosahedral-group-is-isomorphic-to-the-alternating-group-a-5-ne) to prove, in 523 characters of arcane incantation, that the alternating group A5 (ie all rearrangements of five objects that can be created by swapping two objects an even number of times) is isomorphic to the group of rotations of a dodecahedron that map vertices to vertices, edges to edges, and faces to faces. In my mind, 523 characters is far too many -- we can do better!

## Challenge

To solve this challenge, take as input a member a of A5, represented as an even permutation of the first 5 integers, and output a 3x3 rotation matrix that maps a dodecahedron to itself. Your program must be an isomorphism: This means that your program must output a unique rotation matrix for each element a, and for any elements of A5 a, b, c such that a composed with b yields c, then YourProgram(a) * YourProgram(b) = YourProgram(c) (to within  floating point precision, of course). Shortest program wins!

## Example Input and Output

We present as an example one valid isomorphism, but any valid isomorphism is a permitted answer.

[image: Example Dodecahedron]

We assosciate the colored cubes [red, green, yellow, blue, black] with the numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Then, for each permutation a in A5, our example outputs a matrix that rotates the figure shown so as to permute the colored cubes according to a.

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [[1, 0, 0][0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1]]

[2, 3, 1, 4, 5] -> [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]] (a 120 degree rotation along the axis (1, 1, 1)

[3, 4, 1, 2, 5] -> [[-1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, -1]] (a 180 degree rotation along the y axis ie coming towards the viewer)

[4, 2, 3, 5, 1] -> [[-0.3090170,  0.5,  0.8090170]
[0.5,  0.8090170, -0.3090170]
[-0.8090170,  0.3090170, -0.5]]

(a 60 degree rotation along the vector (1 / phi, phi, 0)

Answer (score 1):

**Battleships Board Validation**

Do you know the game Battleship? Well, I want to play with my little brother, but before we can begin we need to set up our ships on the board. This is your input.

Now, we need to check that the ships that we set up are valid. This is where you come in to help. Your task is to write a program or function which checks whether the given 2d array (your board/input) is a valid board or not.

The input will be a 2d array, where `1` represents part of a ship and `0` represents part of the ocean.

**The rules:**

- There must be:

  - One battleship (size 4)
  - Two cruisers (size 3)
  - Three destroyers (size 2)
  - Four submarines (size 1)
- Any additional ships are not allowed, and neither are missing ships
- Each ship must be either vertical or horizontal (aside from submarines, which are a single grid space)
- The ships cannot overlap, but may be adjacent

Solutions may not use streams.

in addition, you must solve this with a `BF` function (normally the class will also be called BF) which receives the 2d array(input) and uses a `validate` function. Afterward, you are free to manipulate the 2d array however you want and add any functions that you want.

here are some more examples that you can use to check your code:
is valid:

```
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

wrong ships, result is false-

```
 {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

missing ships, is false->

```
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

check contact, is true->

```
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

check another one with contact->

```
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

check invalid, is false->

```
 {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

random board which is true->

```
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
```

Who's code will be the shortest byte solution that passes all these examples successfully?! Good luck. ;)

Any language is allowed, but I'd like to see an answer in Java especially.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

link to the original post-
[Validating a Battleship board](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217437/java-validating-a-battleship-board?noredirect=1#comment507130_217437)

this also my first post that I am doing. Whats a good way to decide who is the winner and in what time frame? help would be appreciated

(any sidenotes on how to improve?anything needing clarity?)

Comment: Hi there, new person! I'm happy to see you using the sandbox first! Generally it is good to avoid language-specific challenges. Also, is there a particular reason you're making this a [tag:fastest-code] challenge rather than [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: not really im just used to using java

Comment: not to sure overall what the challenge itself would be so any suggestions would be great

Comment: Hi there. Great first challenge! As others have mentioned, I would drop the Java code to allow all languages, and just give test cases (since I usually answer in Java and 05AB1E, I might still answer in Java when the challenge goes live though ;) ). As for the win-condition, I would suggest to use [code-golf], since it's the most used and popular, and probably most appropriate for this challenge as well. (Code-golf means to create a function/program as short as possible in terms of used bytes.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen would it still be good for me to leave the condition that the input is a 2d array into the BF function and must have the validate function? I think that it also makes it more challenging

Comment: @Rockycohn Input as a 2d array is indeed good. But I would remove the Java function and validate code completely and just allow all languages. You can still mention you prefer to see a Java answer especially, though. [Here a pastebin what I would personally change it to as example.](https://pastebin.com/utxNVsdW)

Comment: gotcha. did it thanks:)

Comment: That looks a lot better. :) I've upvoted and voted to re-open your challenge, since I saw you made the same edit there.

Comment: would it be better to delete the main post repost it since the title has Java and I changed it to all languages?

Comment: Unless there's some rep constraint that I'm not aware of, you should be able to edit the title of the main post. There's no need to repost it. (Or just ping me so that I do the update myself if you're not allowed to for some reason.)

Comment: it doesn't seem to let me @Arnauld if you could remove "Java," from the post that would be great

Comment: Also, please note that you should not [make assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/58563). You should remove things like _Solutions may not use streams_ or _you must solve this with a BF function_.

Comment: Title updated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Solve a Cubic Equation

### Input

- Your program will take in the integer coefficients of the equation \$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\$ as inputs (a, b, c, and d)
- All solutions are between 1000 and -1000.
- a is nonzero

### Output

- All real solutions of the input equation, with an accuracy of at least the thousandths place.

### Rules

- Built-in equation solver are not allowed
- Native math libraries that do not solve equations may be used
- If you have any questions, please ask in comment

### Examples

1. 

Input:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
-1.651
```

Another Valid Output:

```
-1.651 -1.651 -1.651
```

2. 

Input:

```
1 3 0 -1
```

Output:

```
-2.879 -0.653 0.532
```

### Worked Example  (C++) doesn't work with two roots

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDbbsMgDIbv8xRWqiFoaAbp7hL6LsSUzVGaTD1IjdY@ewZJ22iTsQH/nzEybj4Rx3FFHbYXt4fqdHbU51@7hLozHCx1XCQ/CQC4/lK3e7CylihdGVMntJ3n6VvrXyuVzEpWS4aSOTFRvj/yRzGZjVZKlVSZec@MysNBiwhObZZOjaFsVsu/wqCNXVO0rJ4iBnf/oSJATbQAxYjBXxB5PuidUYwNRWXU7Tboar6FpHhAz/8sj14Np6wR70W5SN/HMKk4hXzbekjlVTzFezKF@zhqKGALH78)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double a,b,c,d;
   scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf",&a,&b,&c,&d);
   for(double i=-100;i<=100;i+=0.0001)
   {
      double j=i+0.0001;
      double y1=a*i*i*i+b*i*i+c*i+d;
      double y2=a*j*j*j+b*j*j+c*j+d;
      if(y1>=0&&y2<=0||y1<=0&&y2>=0)
      {
         double x=(i+j)/2;
         printf("%.3lf ",x);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why is the section with your code named "Worked Example", but it doesn't seem to solve the equation `x^3 + x^2 = 0`.

Comment: I'd suggesting guaranteeing that `a` is nonzero so that quadratic or lower cases don't have to be handled. Or, possibly just guarantee a monic polynomial with `a=1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Is this a narrow Thumb instruction?

ARM Thumb was originally a 16-bit only subset of the 32-bit ARM instruction set.

However, later versions added 32-bit "wide" instructions which were more flexible, and called the original, more restrictive 16-bit instructions "narrow" instructions.

The assembler now chooses between narrow and wide instructions automatically, depending on how the instruction was written. However, this meant that the syntax had to be changed to have specific rules.

Your job is to be this assembler.

However, the programs you parse are not that interesting; they will only ever consist of `add` and `adds`.

More specifically:

Your task is to write a function or program that will take an `add`/`adds` instruction, and return a truthy value if it is a valid narrow instruction, or a falsey value if it is not.

#### Syntax rules

- ARM has 16 registers, `r0`-`r12`, `r13` (aka `sp`), `r14` (aka `lr`), and `r15` (aka `pc`). For ease of parsing, we are going to refer to all registers by their number, instead of using the special register names.
- Do note the names when reading the official docs, as there are a lot of special cases for `sp` and `pc`.
- In Thumb mode, these are split into "Lo registers", which are `r0`-`r7`, and "Hi registers" which are `r8`-`r15`. Many instructions can only use Lo registers.
- Many instructions use the same source register as the destination register, even if they are written with three operands.
- `add` and `adds` are distinct instructions. `adds` affects the condition flags, while `add` does not. That is the difference, if you were wondering.

The following 6 forms are valid for narrow instructions (adapted from [here](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289861747.htm)):

1. `adds x, y, #imm`: `x` and `y` must both be Lo registers, and `imm` is a 3-bit constant from `0-7`.
2. `adds x, y, z`: `x`, `y`, and `z` must all be Lo registers.
3. `add x, x, y`: `x` **and/or** `y` must be Hi registers. Note that `x` is repeated twice.

- We are ignoring the fact that ARMv6 relaxed this rule to keep it interesting.

4. `adds x, x, #imm`: `x` must be a Lo register. `imm` is an 8-bit constant from `0-255`. Again, note that `x` is repeated twice.
5. `add r13, r13, #imm`: `imm` is a constant multiple of 4 in the range `0-508`.
6. `add x, y, #imm`: `x` must be a Lo register, and `y` must either be `r13` or `r15`. `imm` is a constant multiple of 4 in the range `0-1020`.

Everything else is either a wide instruction or not valid.

#### Other notes

Standard loopholes, everything must be self-contained, and you are only allowed to treat it as text. You can't feed it to an assembler (unless you include the assembler source code in the result, but..  ｗｈｙ).

The input can either be a string argument or text from stdin.

You can assume the format will match the following format (all lowercase, separators being a single space):

```
{add or adds} reg, reg, {#imm or reg}
```

Where `imm` is a non-negative number in base 10 (yes, including zero).

As a regex pattern:

```
^adds? r([0-9]|1[0-5]), r([0-9]|1[0-5]), (#[0-9]+|r([0-9]|1[0-5]))$
```

#### Reference implementation

In case the rules are difficult to follow, here is a reference implementation I made in C. Yes, I deliberately overabstracted it to make you do all the work.

I resisted the urge to post the reference implementation in ARM Thumb assembly, as that would be genuinely evil.

You will not need to do the same error checking I did here. You can always assume the string itself is valid. The error checks in the main function are mostly to show what CAN'T happen.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct thumb_add_insn {
    char opcode[5];
    uint32_t op1;
    uint32_t op2;
    char op3_prefix;
    uint32_t op3;
};

// Returns whether the opcode ID is adds.
static inline bool is_adds(const char *opcode)
{
    return strcmp(opcode, "adds") == 0;
}

// Returns whether this register ID belongs to a Lo register,
// specifically r0-r7.
static inline bool is_lo_reg(uint32_t reg_id)
{
    return reg_id <= 7;
}

// Returns whether this register ID belongs to a Hi register,
// specifically r8-r15.
static inline bool is_hi_reg(uint32_t reg_id)
{
    return reg_id >= 8;
}

// Returns whether the operand prefix is for an immediate
// value, specifically, '#'.
static inline bool is_imm(char c)
{
    return c == '#';
}

// adds x, y, #imm3
static bool is_form_1(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op1)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op2)
        && is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && insn->op3 <= 7;
}

// adds x, y, z
static bool is_form_2(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op1)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op2)
        && !is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op3);
}

// adds x, x, #imm8
static bool is_form_3(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op1)
        && insn->op1 == insn->op2
        && is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && insn->op3 < 256;
}

// add x, x, y
static bool is_form_4(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return !is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && !is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && (is_hi_reg(insn->op1) || is_hi_reg(insn->op3))
        && insn->op1 == insn->op2;
}

// add r13, r13, #imm
static bool is_form_5(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return !is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && insn->op1 == 13
        && insn->op1 == insn->op2
        && is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && insn->op3 <= 508
        && insn->op3 % 4 == 0;
}

// add x, y, #imm, y == r13 or r15
static bool is_form_6(const struct thumb_add_insn *insn)
{
    return !is_adds(insn->opcode)
        && is_lo_reg(insn->op1)
        && (insn->op2 == 13 || insn->op2 == 15)
        && is_imm(insn->op3_prefix)
        && insn->op3 <= 1020
        && insn->op3 % 4 == 0;
}

// Parses a Thumb add/adds instruction.
// Returns 1 if it is a narrow instruction, 0 if it is not,
// and -1 on an error.
int is_narrow_add(const char *str)
{
    // Note that you do not have to do error checking for the
    // competition.

    if (str == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate a 24 byte struct on the heap for good measure
    struct thumb_add_insn *insn = calloc(1, sizeof(*insn));
    if (insn == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Parse the instruction with sscanf.
    // {adds} r{0}, r{3}, {#}{3}
    if (sscanf(str, "%4s r%"SCNu32", r%"SCNu32", %c%"SCNu32,
               insn->opcode,
               &insn->op1,
               &insn->op2,
               &insn->op3_prefix,
               &insn->op3) != 5
       || (strcmp(insn->opcode, "add") != 0
          && strcmp(insn->opcode, "adds") != 0)
       || insn->op1 > 15
       || insn->op2 > 15
       || (insn->op3_prefix != 'r' && insn->op3_prefix != '#')
       || (insn->op3_prefix == 'r' && insn->op3 > 15)
    ) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        free(insn);
        return -1;
    }

    int ret;
    // Test against each of the forms
    if (is_form_1(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (is_form_2(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (is_form_3(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (is_form_4(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (is_form_5(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (is_form_6(insn)) {
        ret = 1;
    } else { // not a match
        ret = 0;
    }

    free(insn);
    return ret;
}
```

#### Test cases

```c
adds r6, r3, #0    // true, form 1
adds r0, r1, #7    // true, form 1
add r0, r1, #3     // false, must be "adds"
adds r0, r9, #1    // false, r9 is a Hi register
adds r0, r1, #9    // false, must be 0-7

adds r0, r0, r0    // true, form 2
adds r7, r1, r2    // true, form 2
adds r4, r4, r1    // true, form 2
add r7, r1, r2     // false, must be "adds"
adds r13, r14, r6  // false, r13 and r14 are Hi registers (this isn't even valid as a wide instruction)

adds r0, r0, #0    // true, form 3
adds r5, r5, #249  // true, form 3
add r6, r6, #31    // false, must be "adds"
adds r3, r3, #256  // false, must be 0-255
adds r8, r8, #72   // false, r8 is a Hi register

add r4, r4, r11    // true, form 4
add r8, r8, r5     // true, form 4
add r9, r9, r9     // true, form 4
add r14, r14, r12  // true, form 4
add r8, r9, r10    // false, Rd must be the same
add r1, r1, r0     // false, one must be a Hi register (we are ignoring the ARMv6 change)

add r13, r13, #0   // true, form 5
add r13, r13, #48  // true, form 5
adds r13, r13, #64 // false, must be "add"
add r13, r13, #17  // false, not a multiple of 4
add r13, r13, #512 // false, must be 0-508

add r0, r15, #0    // true, form 6
add r4, r13, #1000 // true, form 6
add r11, r13, #32  // false, r11 is a Hi register
add r2, r13, #4000 // false, must be 0-1020
adds r7, r15, #384 // false, must be "add"
add r3, r15, #127  // false, not a multiple of 4
```

Things you can safely ignore:

```c
// String will never be empty
adds r1, r2 // don't worry about implicit middle operand
adds R4, #12 // same
adds r3, r3, #-3 // adding a negative is not even a thing
add r0, r0, r99 // the only registers are r0 - r15
add r13, r13, #0x32 // it is base 10
subs r1, r1, r2 // only add and adds need to be handled
add r2, r2, lr // you don't need to handle the special names
add r0, sp, #0 // same
add #3, r1, r1 // only the last one will be an immediate
adds r3, r3, 32 // all immediates are prefixed with #
ADDS R0, R0, R1 // everything is lowercase
adds        r2,     r3 , r4 // only one space
adds r2,r3,r4 // there will always be spaces
addeq r0, r0, r1 // no IT blocks
adds.n r0, r0, r1 // no manual width specifiers
add r1, r2, r3, lsl #8 // no barrel shifting
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes per language wins.

Proposed tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) and maybe [assembly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) but I think that is for things you must write in assembly, not parsing assembly itself.

Answer (score 1):

## Hanabi playing bot

### Overview

[Hanabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanabi_(card_game)) is a **cooperative card game with limited communication**. It won the German "Spiel des Jahres" award in 2013.

The game can be played by 2-5 players, each of which has a hand of 5 cards (4 cards for 4-5 players), which they can't see themselves, but the other players can. In each turn, you can either play or discard a card, or give one other player a hint about their cards.

Common goal is to play out the cards in each color in ascending order.

As this is a cooperative game, each answer needs to cooperate with other instances of itself.

### I/O format

#### Option 1: stateless, for all languages

Your program is called once for each turn (and is supposed to terminate afterwards). It will receive the current game state via standard input, and reply with an action via standard output.
Invalid output means this game is counted as forfeited (lost, 0 points).

**Input**

Input is a line-based ASCII-format, with a prefix indicating what kind of data it is.
The last line of the input is the current turn number (see below).
Input will be in this order:

1. Meta-information:
   `n:`  **n** = number of players (2 .. 5)
   `y:`  **you** = own player id (1 .. n)
2. visible cards of the other players:

   - `c 1:` cards for player 1
   - ...
   - `c` **n**`:` cards for player **n**

   The cards for **you** are omitted in the list (you don't see your own cards).

   Each card has a color (one of `r`, `y`, `g`, `b`, `w`) and a
   number (`1` to `5`), written like `r1` or `y5`, comma-separated.

   Example: `c 2: w4,y1,g2,r3` means that player 2 has a white 4,
   a yellow 1, a green 2 and a red 3, in this order, on her hand.
3. Hints given about each player's cards, in a similar list:

   - `h 1:`  hints for player 1
   - ...
   - `h` **n**`:` hints for player **n**

   For each card (in the same order as before), all hints are noted,
   in a comma-separated list.
   We also note negative information, i.e. when a card was present
   when a hint was given, but was not selected, by prefixing with `!`.
   For example `5` is a card which is known as `5` but of unknown color,
   `w1` is a card which is known as a white 1, `3!y` is a 3 which is
   known as not yellow, `g!15` is a green card which is known as
   neither being a 1 nor 5.

   For example, `h 2: ,y!2,2!yr,r` means that for player 2, the first card is
   completely unknown (was taken after the last hint), the second card is known
   as yellow and as not a 2, the third card is known as a 2 which is neither
   red nor yellow, and the fourth card is known as red.
4. `p` *color*`:` *number* – already (successfully) played out cards (one per line).
   Here we just note the highest card of each color.

   - `p r: 2` means for red, the 1 and two were played out
     (i.e. red 3 is the next one to play).
   - `p w: 0` means no white card was played out yet (i.e. the
     white 1 is the next one to play).
5. `d:`  – Discarded cards
   A list of all cards which were either intentionally discarded or
   unsuccessfully played out, comma-separated.

   For example, `d: w3,b5,y2,y2` means that white 3, blue 5 and
   two yellow 2s were already discarded.
6. game status information (each on one line, in this order):
   `lh:`  number of hints left,
   `ld:`  number of discards left *(those two always sum to 8)*,
   `lb:`  number of "bad plays" left
   `lc:`  number of cards left in the deck
   `t:`  current turn number

(The input will be closed here.)

**Output**

The action to take. One of

- `h`  player-id   color or number – give a hint to another player.
  E.g. `h 4 y` will give player 4 a hint which of his cards are yellow. `h 3 1`
  will give player 3 a hint which of her cards are a 1. This action is only possible
  if the number of hints left is positive.
  *(The number of hints left will be reduced by 1, the number of discards will be increased by 1.)*
- `p`  card# – play one of your own cards (identified by its number (1..5)).
  *(If this card fits into the cards already played, it's added there.
  (If this is the last 5, the game ends immediately with full score (25)).
  Otherwise it is discarded and the number of bad plays is reduced by 1.
  If it reaches 0, the game ends (unsuccessfully).)*
- `d`  card# – discard one of your own cards (idenfified by its number (1..5)).
  This is only possible if the number of discards is positive.
  *(The number of hints left will be increased by 1, the number of discards will reduced by 1).*

*After playing or discarding a card, this card is removed from the hand, and a new card is drawn from the deck and is added to the list of cards of this player (on the left). (The hints are automatically updated.)*

#### Option 2 (stateful)

Your program receives a live transcript of everything what happens (including the actions of the other players, and the results thereof).
The controller will read one line of output from the program when it's its turn.

**Input**

Most input lines have the same format as before.

Initial input (as for the stateless version):

1. Meta information (`n:` , `y:` )
2. other player's cards (as before)
3. hints for cards (as before)
4. played cards (initially just `p r: 0`, `p w: 0`, etc.)
5. discarded cards (initially just `d:` )
6. game status, ending with `t: 1`.

After each player's turn:

1. a line is given with that player's action:
   `a` *player id*`:`   the action as defined in the output, e.g.
   `a 1: h 4 y` means that player 1 gave a hint to player 4 about yellow cards
2. Those parts of the card situation which changed, e.g. `c` and `d` lines if
   a player discarded a card (or unsuccessfully played a card) and drew a new
   one), `c` and `p` lines if a player played out a card successfully,
   a `h` line if a player gave a hint.
3. Updated status information, e.g. `lh` + `ld` when hint was given or a
   card discarded, `lc` when a new card was drawn, `lb` when a card was
   played unsuccessfully.
4. `t:`  indicating the next turn number.

*(TODO: Do we need an indication that's now ***your** turn? That can be calculated by y == t mod n, but an explicit prompt might be easier to handle.*

When the game ends, the input will be closed. (Your bot should terminate then.)

**Output**

As in the stateless version, one line indicating the player's action.

#### Option 3/4 (JVM only, stateless or statefull)

To be defined. As I will be writing the controller in a JVM language, it should be possible/easy to provide a Java API to be implemented by the bots.

### Other game rules:

I tried to give most of the details above, but here are some which might be missing/unclear:

- There are three × 1, two × 2 to 4 and one 5 in each of the five colors
  (50 cards in total, 10 per color).
- When playing with 2 or 3 players, each player has 5 cards, when playing
  with 4 or 5 players, each player has 4 cards in their hand.
- If you have three bad plays (i.e. the `lb` counter reaches 0), you lose
  immediately. This is counted as score 0.
- If you succeed to play all 25 cards (i.e. all 5s are played successfully),
  you win immediately, with a score of 25.
- When the drawing deck is exhausted, one more round is played (i.e. each
  player has one more turn), then the game ends and the final score is
  the number of cards successfully played out.

### Competition Rules

- While for human play, the amount of extra communication is "subject to negotiation",
  here I want to explore what is possible with just what the rules provide.
  **Any communication between your bot instances** (except as provided by
  the defined interface, i.e. via game actions) **is strictly forbidden**.
  Strategy needs to be encoded in the source code, not discussed during the game.
- There is also no communication between your individual games (i.e. no persistence).
- I will nominate an overall winner, and one for the stateless category.
  (The stateful ones have a bit more information, so they could emulate the
  stateless ones.)
- I will run contestants 1000 times with random decks of cards, once for
  each number of players from 2 to 5. If your bot only works with a
  specific number of players, state this in your answer.
  The competition score is the average score for all the runs. [I'll need
  to experiment to see how this varies, maybe I'll increase or decrease
  the count.]
- A bot needs to provide output in a reasonable time (to be defined). The stateless
  version needs to terminate after providing output, the stateful one keeps
  running, but should terminate after end of input (i.e. after the game ended).
- I will provide the controller on Github, feel free to test your bot with it
  (and compare it with other competition entries).
- The programming language needs to have an interpreter or compiler which is
  available free of cost for Ubuntu 20.4 (otherwise I can't run your bot to
  score it).
- I reserve the right to not run a bot when I suspect malicious code in it.
- This is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), please keep your code readable.

Comment: This still needs to be refined, and I actually need to write (and test) the controller. I won't post it before that is done.

Comment: What tags should this get? [tag:code-competition]?

Answer (score 1):

## Write a Length interpreter

Length is a simple stack-based esolang where instructions are encoded as line lengths
The instruction set is as follows:

| Line Length | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | `inp` | Pushes the ascii value of the first byte of stdin to the stack. |
| 10 | `add` | Adds the top two values on the stack and pushes the result onto the stack. |
| 11 | `sub` | Subtracts the top two values on the stack and pushes the result onto the stack. |
| 12 | `dup` | Duplicates the top value of the stack. |
| 13 | `cond` | If the top value of the stack is 0, skip the next instruction. Then pop it. |
| 14 | `gotou` | Sets the program counter to the value of the line under the instruction. |
| 15 | `outn` | Pops the top of the stack, and outputs it as a number. |
| 16 | `outa` | Pops the top of the stack, and outputs its ascii value. |
| 20 | `mul` | Multiplies the top two values on the stack and pushes the result onto the stack. |
| 21 | `div` | Divides the top two values on the stack and pushes the result onto the stack. |
| 24 | `gotos` | Sets the program counter to the value at the top of the stack |

In case the table doesn't work, here is the esolangs page: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Length
Test inputs are too long to put here, they can be found [here](https://github.com/LengthLang/length)
`helloworld.len` - Outputs `Hello, World!`
`truth.len` - A truth machine
`bottles.len` - Outputs the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer
This is a code golf, so shortest program wins!

Comment: table is broken, it looks fine in preview

Comment: Fixed. But this should be reported on SE Meta.

Answer (score 1):

## Finish what John McCarthy started (WIP) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisp)

This does not have anything to do with Joseph McCarthy or communism. Some background from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-expression) (you can skip ahead if you like):

> John McCarthy published the first [paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.pdf) on Lisp in 1960 while a research fellow at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology. In it he
> described a language of symbolic expressions (S-expressions) that
> could represent complex structures as lists. Then he defined a set of
> primitive operations on the S-expressions, and a language of
> meta-expressions (M-expressions) that could be used to define more
> complex operations. Finally, he showed how the meta-language itself
> could be represented with S-expressions, resulting in a system that
> was potentially self-hosting.[3] The draft version of this paper is
> known as "AI Memo 8".<sup>[[4](https://www.informatimago.com/develop/lisp/com/informatimago/small-cl-pgms/aim-8/index.html)]</sup>
>
> Example M-expressions
> [image]
>
> McCarthy had planned to develop an
> automatic Lisp compiler (LISP 2) using M-expressions as the language
> syntax and S-expressions to describe the compiler's internal
> processes. Stephen B. Russell read the paper and suggested to him that
> S-expressions were a more convenient syntax. Although McCarthy
> disapproved of the idea, Russell and colleague Daniel J. Edwards
> hand-coded an interpreter program that could execute S-expressions.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgzM.png)
> This program was adopted by McCarthy's research group, establishing
> S-expressions as the dominant form of Lisp.

## Task

Interpret a subset of M-expressions, where 9 primitive functions have already been defined.

### Syntax

**Atoms**: An atom is a series of any characters excluding `[`, `]`, `;`. While an atom name can include whitespace, leading and trailing whitespace is ignored. Some examples include `foo`, `lambda` (also a function name), and `nil` (also a list). Atoms act as both variables and data (they're like strings).

**Booleans**: The atom `t` is truthy, whereas the atom `nil` is falsy.

**`quote`**: A series of expressions between square brackets, delimited by semicolons. `[a; [b; c]; de]` is equivalent to the S-expression `(QUOTE (A (B C) DE))`. It is somewhat like this JS list: `["a", ["b", "c"], "de"]`.

**`cond`**: A series of if-then pairs between square brackets, delimited by semicolons, with an arrow `->` (you can use any other character(s)) separating the if-then pairs. e.g. `[atom[x] -> x; t -> car[x]]` yields `x` if it's an atom, or the first element of `x` if it's a list. It is guaranteed that at least one of the cases will be true.

**Function application**: Functions can be called using `functionname[arg1; arg2; ...; argN]`.

- `car` - Return the first element of its argument.
- `cdr` - Return its argument without the first element.
- `cons` - Prepend its first argument to its second argument.
- `eq` - Check if its two arguments are equal.
- `atom` - Check if its argument is an atom.
- `lambda` - Define an anonymous function using the syntax `lambda[[param1; param2; ...; paramN]; bodythatusesparams]`.
- `label` - Store a function using a name. For example, `label[drop2; lambda[[xs]; cdr[cdr[xs]]]]` defines a function `drop2` that drops the first two elements of its first argument.

## Rules

- Functions may use lexical or dynamic scope, or some crazy mixture of both.

<sub>Much of this question is copied from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103257/95792) and the Wikipedia article on M-expressions.</sub>

## Questions for Meta

- For `cond`, should I use the `[condition -> res; condition2 -> res2; ...]` syntax, or should I keep it like the linked [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103257/95792)?
- Should answers support higher-order functions?
- Does anyone have any good examples using Mexprs?

Comment: I did a double-take at the title, which sounds like the challenge is to root out communists still hiding in the US state department to finish what Joseph McCarthy started...

Comment: @xnor Uh...that certainly was not what I intended. I could probably say "Finish what John McCarthy started" or just "Interpret M-expressions", although the latter sounds more boring. There's also a Eugene McCarthy, apparently, so I guess just McCarthy is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

## Radiation Showdown (WIP)

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

---

Two radiation-hardened programs will go head-to-head to destroy each other.

Your task is to create a program which takes the other program's source as input and output the index of the byte that should be deleted from the other program. (zero-indexed)

Each program will be radiated at the same time. The first program to fail to return a valid index after being radiated loses (whether by compiler error, runtime exception, out-of-bounds output, or some other means), or it is considered a draw if both fail at the same time.

Each program will compete against each other program. The program receives 1 point per round survived. The overall winner is the one with the most points.

Programs are limited to a length of 1024 bytes.

---

Alternate possibilities:

(Inspired by @Dingus) A hash of the opponent's original source code and a list of the indexes of bytes deleted so far is passed in instead of the current source code, making it a bit more of a blind guess as to what you radiate. If at any time, a program makes a guess it has already made, it loses. This turns it into a sort of "Radiation Battleship"

Comment: Interesting challenge. How will it be tested, if different languages are allowed?

Comment: @user it shouldn't be terribly difficult to make a shell-based controller. Submissions would probably need to include compiler flags or shebangs separately so that the controller knows exactly how to run the program.

Comment: That would work for "practical" languages, but I'm a bit worried about esolangs. I guess TIO can probably deal with that, though.

Comment: If Program A has all its bytes deleted before Program B does, does B win? I'm imagining a pathological scenario in which A is empty and outputs by exit code.

Comment: Also, wouldn't something like [this](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/32AUjIJRMGLB//8A "Japt – Try It Online") be impossible to beat?

Comment: @Dingus I suppose that would be impossible to beat. I wonder how I could make things different with resisting arbitrary insertions... probably not viable though.

Comment: To prevent fixed-output programs, could you perhaps tie the indexing to the unmodified code? In other words, force the output to be different every round?

Comment: @Dingus I think that might work (implying that both the original program and guesses are passed to the program), but there's probably another similar edge case I'm missing. Kinda turns it into radiation battleship. If a program returns a guess it has already made, it instantly loses.

Comment: Following that thought, it might be kind of interesting if some opaque id (e.g. a hash of the source code) is passed in instead of the current state of the source code.

Comment: @Beefster what's the point of the hash? (what can submissions do with it?)

Comment: @thedefault. the hash is only used to assign a distinct id to each program and it could be used to seed a random number generator.

Comment: @Beefster I thought submissions aren't supposed to be designed to beat specific opponents (and the only way to use a hash is to optimize to beat specific opponents) (and providing a hash of an unknown string as input just in case somebody wants to seed a RNG with it is a weird decision)

Comment: Also, if the length of the source code is not known, it's effectively impossible to make guesses that are guaranteed not to be out-of-bounds. (also, I expect 90% answers to this challenge to output something like `0,1,2,3,4,5,...`)

Answer (score 1):

## Print a 3D shape

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/print-a-3d-shape)

Comment: Suggestion: use characters other than `•` and `¶` as they are multi-byte characters which not all languages will handle easily. ASCII characters instead would be better

Comment: I modified them, thank you.

Comment: @caridCoinheringaahing I was just looking to try some other character taking as reference [this ASCII table](https://www.haghish.com/statistics/stata-blog/stata-programming/ascii_characters_mobile.php). The two characters that I changed are numbers 166 and 167 of the table. I am confused.

Comment: Most languages can handle code points between 32 and 127 inclusive. Some use custom code pages (e.g. Jelly) that won't necessarily have extended ASCII characters, but will have regular ASCII

Comment: Oh all right thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Davide the table you linked is not actually an ASCII table. ASCII only goes from 0 to 127; there are more [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) that extend it to 256 and the creator of that table has clearly picked one. This confusion arises because almost all code pages include ASCII as the first 128 and then extend with some symbols like `¶` on top of that. Nowadays most things use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8) which encodes some characters with more than one byte and can use millions of different characters from [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

Comment: @pxeger Oh thank you for this definitive explanation!

Answer (score 1):

## Counting set bits in a byte

Here is a bite-sized problem I ran in to when trying to implement [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) on a microcontroller, and was trying to count the amount of neighbours: How can you check how many bits are set in a byte?

### Challenge

Given one byte of input data and an integer N between 0 and 8, check if there are exactly N bits set in the byte.

### Test cases

```
N = 0, input = 0b00000001 -> False 
N = 0, input = 0b00000000 -> True 
N = 3, input = 0b01001001 -> True 
N = 3, input = 0b11100000 -> True 
N = 3, input = 0b00001111 -> False 
N = 7, input = 0b11101111 -> True 
N = 7, input = 0b11111110 -> True 
N = 8, input = 0b11111111 -> False
```

## Sandbox question

- My first intuition to solving this problem was to shift the bits out one by one, AND with 0x01 and count them. I feel however it must be possible to do something more efficient in terms of CPU cycles used. How can I make a challenge that is about optimizing instruction count and memory usage rather than on program-size? I have seen the [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) tag, but I don't know what scoring method best to use.

## Edit: Closing after some good comments and possible solutions

Arnauld and CristoLosoph gave some great comments and led me to conclude that my issue is maybe to hardware/language specific to fit in a nice coding challenge. CristoLosoph showed me this interesting code snippet which I think is quite efficient:

```
uint8_t count_bits(uint8_t x){
     x = ((x & 0b10101010) >> 1) + (x & 0b01010101); 
     x = ((x & 0b11001100) >> 2) + (x & 0b00110011); 
     x = ((x & 0b11110000) >> 4) + (x & 0b00001111); 
     return x;
}
```

Two other things I learned:

- Some hardware have a [builtin `POPCNT` instruction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47873/77496) in their instruction set, and gcc has a `__builtin_popcount()` method that does exactly what I was looking for
- I found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949935/calculate-number-of-bits-set-in-byte) that it's an interesting trade-off (as with most embedded functions probably) to just make a lookup table containing all 256 possible return values. It takes some memory but not too much.

I also learned that [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) probably would have been a good fit for this type of challenge!

Once again thanks for the interesting comments!

Comment: Hello RvdV.   Hm, seems like your motivation does not really fit. Fastest-code and smallest code is not the same, rather opposite things. When you program microcontrollers you are very restricted in the language but code golfing is the opposite (if you do not specifically restrict languages to one single one). Of course, there is a very performant solution for bitcount in the language which you might be looking for which however is quite uninteresting for code golf.  I'll post you a fast snippet in C below.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47870/58563).

Comment: You may consider using [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/atomic-code-golf/info), but be aware that it's pretty hard to specify correctly.

Comment: x = ((x & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1) + (x & 0x55555555);
x = ((x & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2) + (x & 0x33333333);
x = ((x & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4) + (x & 0x0F0F0F0F);
x = ((x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8) + (x & 0x00FF00FF);
x = ((x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16) + (x & 0x0000FFFF);
You only need the first 3 lines if you only need it for 8-bit integers and then you can cut the hexadecimal literals down to two digits.

Comment: But if you work with GCC, please use __builtin_popcount() since that is the function that the compiler people tried to optimize exactly for your purpose and for your selected architecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Arnauld and ChrisoLosoph! You are right that it's hard to define, and I didn't realize even how much language but also hardware-bound my problem was, maybe it's too difficult to define indeed (and if you define it language-agnostic it becomes the related post Arnauld linked). I will update the post with you suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

## Quine Countdown! [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program that accepts a single parameter n and outputs another program that outputs another program etc until the nth call outputs the original input n again.

Scoring is a modified version of codegolf: For input `100`, add together the code length of each program in the chain, excluding the final `100`. This is your score. Lowest score wins!

Comment: Actually it's not much harder than a typical quine program. Because 100 is so large, most programs will do it the  general quine way.

Comment: Besides, the score would be easier to read if the score is the average size instead of the maximum.

Comment: "Because 100 is so large, most programs will do it the general quine way."
That's the intention. It's a quine with something extra. Without the scoring rule, everyone would just build nested multi-escaped prints, which isn't as interesting.

Answer (score 1):

## Mix my colors

This challenge is inspired by the [Color Alchemy Patch](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Alchemy#Color_alchemy) on NetHack, notably incorporated by UnNetHack 3.5.2.

### Objective

Given two strings indicating colors, mix them according to the rules below, then output it.

### Colors

There are 16 colors in total that are valid inputs. They are categorized to 8 **chromaticities** and 2 **brightnesses**, like below:

```
        Light    Dark
Hueless white    black
Red     pink     ruby
Blue    sky-blue indigo
Yellow  yellow   golden
Orange  orange   amber
Green   emerald  dark-green
Purple  puce     magenta
Brown   ochre    brown
```

(I'm omitting `gray`, for it will make this challenge just cumbersome in this regard.)

Note that all color names are in lowercase.

### Color-mixing rules

- Above all, mixing colors is idempotent.
- Mixing colors is commutative unless noted below.
- When mixing two primary colors (Red, Blue, or Yellow):

  - If they have same chromaticities, the result will also be in the same chromaticity.
  - Mixing Red and Blue results in Purple.
  - Mixing Red and Yellow results in Orange.
  - Mixing Blue and Yellow results in Green.
- When mixing two secondary colors (Orange, Green, or Purple):

  - If they have same chromaticities, the result will also be in the same chromaticity.
  - All other combinations result in Brown.
- For all cases covered by above, mixing two Light (resp. Dark) colors will result in corresponding Light (resp. Dark) color.
- For all cases covered by above, mixing a Light color and a Dark color shall result in **either** Light or Dark. This is the only rule that may break the commutativity.
- Mixing a Light color with `black` results in corresponding Dark.
- Mixing a Dark color with `white` results in corresponding Light.
- All combinations not covered by above fall in *don't care* situation.

### Examples

#### Valid outputs

- Mixing `white` and `white` results in `white`.
- Mixing `pink` and `pink` results in `pink`.
- Mixing `pink` and `ruby` results in either `pink` or `ruby`.
- Mixing `ruby` and `golden` results in `amber`.
- Mixing `sky-blue` and `ruby` results in either `puce` or `magenta`.
- Mixing `emerald` and `dark-green` results in either `emerald` or `dark-green`.
- Mixing `emerald` and `orange` results in `ochre`.
- Mixing `puce` and `amber` results in either `ochre` or `brown`.
- Mixing `white` and `ruby` results in `pink`.
- Mixing `ochre` and `black` results in `brown`.

#### *Don't care* situations

- Mixing `pink` and `white` falls in *don't care* situation. There is no rule that covers this case.
- Mixing `ochre` and `brown` falls in *don't care* situation. There is no analogous rule for tertiary colors.
- Mixing `indigo` and `magenta` falls in *don't care* situation. There is no rule for mixing a primary color and a secondary color.
- Mixing `indigo` and `orange` falls in *don't care* situation.
- Mixing `pink` and `ochre` falls in *don't care* situation.
- Mixing `white` and `black` falls in *don't care* situation. (In the game, it results in `gray`, but I'll ignore this, for sake of simplicity of this challenge.)

### Rules for code golf

- Input format is flexible. In particular, it can be two strings, or one string separating colors by whitespaces. It's implementation-defined whether to accept leading or trailing whitespaces.
- Output format is also flexible. Outputting leading or trailing whitespaces is okay.
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

Comment: The rule looks clear enough, but you can provide a table of 256 possible outputs just to be extra sure.

Answer (score 1):

## Golf this Thumb-2 constant!

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218763/94093).

Comment: Not very related to the question, but have you tried using some size-optimization option of some existing compiler? (`-Os`)

Comment: Otherwise, clear enough.

Comment: I explained the pattern better, and the last pattern **does** cover the rest, but it isn't the **shortest**.

Comment: Okay. (just to check, there are \$4862 > 2^{12} = 4096\$ distinct values represented with the Imm12 format, right?)

Comment: Yes. There are 4096 possible encodings for the Imm12 format.

Comment: Then I must understand something wrong, because (as I've said above) there are 4862 different values that can be encoded.)

Comment: Oh yeah I was wrong. I think I am going to go back to it just being a byte rotated, even if it isn't accurate. As the true encoding is too complex to be fun to calculate. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

## Longest Common Suffix

Given arbitrarily many (more than 4) words, your goal is to find the longest common suffix of all of them.

### Rules

1. The suffix shouldn't be longer than one third of the length of any word, and should be longer than 2 characters.
2. The words can have at most one "exception" among them, that is, it doesn't have the same suffix others have. You should ignore these "exceptions".
3. If no suffix can satisfy all rules above, do not make any output.
4. All given words are separated by spaces; they only contain lower case English alphabets.
5. You can use any way to accept input, but output should only be in `STDOUT`.

### Example

```
Given: television operation delegation repetition
Output: ion
```

```
Given: vision decision subtraction observation
Output:
```

Why? The suffix, `ion`, is longer than 1/3 the length of `vision` and `decision`. There're two exceptions.

```
Given: interested congratulated excited overjoyed
Output: ted
```

Why? `overjoyed` is an exception, because others have the suffix `ted`, but it doens't. So we ignore the word `overjoyed`.

```
Given: abcdefghijkl bcdefghijkl cdefghijkl defghijkl
Output: jkl
```

Why? `defghijkl` is the longest, but it is longer than 1/3 the length of `defghijkl`.

**This is code golf, so the shortest code win.**

**It's not recommended to use built-in functions which directly returns the result.**

Comment: Most answerers prefer "any (standard) way to get output" as well, but it's up to you. Practically, it's mostly not a problem.

Comment: Regarding the output "No common...", people don't like hard coding long error messages, it would be better received if it's changed to "any value that signifies that there isn't...".

Answer (score 1):

## Next to the middle

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218714/next-to-the-middle)

Comment: Clearly defined enough (not very interesting) -- except that is it guaranteed that the value exists?

Comment: @user202729 Oh thank you, I forgot to cover this. I think that in case it doesn't exist, we can output a something like the smallest integer in the array. I would like to not restrict the input at all.

Comment: Possible test case: empty array. (by the way don't patch "edit" into the sandbox post, include it in the text itself)

Comment: @user202729 thank you, I edited the challenge. I will add test cases, including the empty array.

Answer (score 1):

## Compile Roman Numerals to <some language>

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[roman-numerals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-numerals)

Your code will, given an integer `i`, output code `code(i)` in any programming language that will evaluate to (print, push, return) `i` by itself. `code(i) ++ code(i')` should evaluate to `i + i'` for an `i' <= i` and `i' - i` for an `i' > i`. You do not have to handle cases like `code(1) ++ code(2) ++ code(3)` where there are more than one number less than `3` before `3`, but you should handle `code(5) ++ code(3) ++ code(4) => 6` with more than two numbers.

**Clarification**: the generating code takes a *number*, not a roman numeral, but the generated code is expected to have the behaviour of a roman numeral when concatenated with other outputs.

### Examples

```
if  yourcode(10) -> 'X'
and yourcode(5)  -> 'V'
then eval('XV')  -> 15.

if  yourcode(1)  -> 'I'
and yourcode(10) -> 'X'
and yourcode(5)  -> 'V'
then eval('XIV') -> 14

if  yourcode(7)  -> 'a'
and yourcode(3)  -> 'b'
then eval('ab')  -> 10
and  eval('ba')  -> 4
```

### Scoring

Your answer is scored by the total bytes of the *generating* code.

Comment: Sandbox: how do I explain this? what tags does this get as a challenge that requires an answer that generates code?

Comment: Any upper limit?

Comment: @Adám no, besides any restrictions on integers built-in to the language.

Comment: This sounds very difficult. The code snippets would need to carry a state.

Comment: Can the code take something  like 7 (not representable as a single character in Roman numeral) as input?

Comment: @user202729 yes, they would need to handle other numbers

Comment: What should something like `eval(code(7) + code(5))` evaluate to?

Comment: @user202729 13 because 7 > 5.

Comment: How do you define "Roman numeral" then? (when digits can take values other than the standard values)

Comment: @user202729 OK, I've now defined how any integers should be handled when next to eachother.

Comment: So, given a sequence \$p_1,\ldots p_n\$ where there's no \$p_i < p_{i+1} < p_{i+2}\$, the result of \$\operatorname{exec}(\operatorname{generate}(p_1) + \ldots + \operatorname{generate}(p_n))\$ (where \$+\$ denotes concatenation) should be \$p_n + \sum _{i=1} ^{n-1} p_i \times (-1)^{[p_i < p_{i+1}]}\$, right?

Comment: @user202729 I guess so, although I'm not good at reading math :P.

Answer (score 1):

(this is the core of the BF memory optimizer challenge.)

(At the moment I still need to make some test cases; however you can still review the rest of the challenge.)

**note**: This problem is reducible from Simple Max Cut, therefore it's NP-complete. (https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(76)90059-1)

**note**: While I did get a bunch of test cases from this site, I'm not sure how can I write a reasonable algorithm to compete with...

---

#### Proof

(actually this is not part of the sandbox challenge, but I'll post it here because it's related)

---

First, for convenience, assume that the problem is represented by a undirected graph, where the number of rows/columns of the matrix is equal to the number of nodes, and the corresponding weight is the sum of the value of the edges connecting the corresponding two nodes.

With that representation, the value to be minimized is the sum of the product of the edge lengths and the edge weights, with the graph nodes embedded into the point \$ 1, 2,\ldots, |V| \$.

---

From a Simple Max Cut problem of the form:

> Given \$ n \$ variables \$ x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n \$, maximize the value of \$ \sum_{i=1}^m [a_i \ne b_i] \$, where each of \$ a_i, b_i \$ represents either a variable or its negation.

It can be transformed to an instance of this problem:

First, construct \$ 2n \$ nodes on a graph, denoted \$ p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_n, q_1, q_2,\ldots, q_n \$. Let \$ a \$ be some positive integer.
Connect those vertices:

- \$ p_1 \$ and \$ q_1 \$, with cost \$ 2n^2 a \$,
- the 4 pairs of vertices \$(p_1, p_i),(p_1, q_i),(q_1, p_i),(q_1, q_i)\$ with cost \$ (n+1-i) a \$, for each \$ i=2, 3,\ldots, n \$,
- and some other edges with small weights (the sum of their weights should be less than \$a\$ -- (1)) that mainly does not affect the optimal configuration.

The sum of the edge weights (except the first one) is \$ 4 ((n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+1)a=2n(n-1)a \$.

The edge between \$ p_1 \$ and \$ q_1 \$ has a weight larger than the sum of all the others, it's obvious to see that in the optimal (minimum cost) configuration, these two must be adjacent.

Then, regardless where those 2 vertices are placed, the \$ i \$'th smallest distance-pair to those are at least the \$ i \$'th value in the sequence are

$$(1, 2),(1, 2),(2, 3),(2, 3),(3, 4),(3, 4),\ldots,(n-1, n),(n-1, n)$$

.

And by the rearrangement inequality, it's optimal to place the weight so that the vertices with the smaller edge-weight to \$ p_1, q_1 \$ are placed further from the vertices. Therefore the only optimal placement is

$$z_n, z_{n-1}, \ldots, z_2, z_1, z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_{n-1}, z_n$$

where each \$ z_i \$ is either \$ p_i \$ or \$ q_i \$ (\$1 \le i \le n\$).

---

Encode the condition "vertex \$ i \$ is on the left side of the cut" by "\$ p_i \$ is to the left of \$ q_i \$ in the permutation". (2)

Assuming that the edge weights are allowed to be fractional.

For each condition (in the Simple Max Cut problem) that "there's an edge between vertices \$u\$ and \$v\$ (\$ u\le v \$)", add an edge between \$ p_u \$ and \$ q_v \$ with weight \$\frac 1 {2u-1}\$ to this problem.

The weight of this edge can either be \$ u-v \$ or \$ u-v+(2u-1)\$ in the configuration that minimizes the total weight of the edges constructed in the previous section.

Therefore, if the vertices \$ u \$ and \$ v \$ are on different sides of the cut (according to the encoding (2)), the total weight is decreased by \$ 1 \$ if \$ u \$ and \$ v \$ are on different sides; and the configuration with the minimum weight is exactly the one with maximum number of edges cut.

However, in the actual problem edge weights must be an integer. We replace each edge weight \$\frac 1 {2u-1} \$ by \$\lceil\frac c {2u-1}\rceil \$, where \$ c=2nm\$.

Because there are \$ m \$ edges in total, if the sum of any \$ k-1 \$ increment values \$\lceil\frac c {2u-1}\rceil (2u-1) \$ is strictly less than the sum of any \$ k \$ increment values, for \$1\le k\le m \$, then the optimal sum is also the maximum cut.

Observe that because \$ c=2nm \$ and \$ x\le 2n-1 \$, each increment value must be between \$ 2nm \$ (inclusive) and \$ 2nm+2n-1 \$ (exclusive). Therefore the maximum sum of \$ k-1 \$ values is \$ (2nm+2n-2)(k-1) \$, which is less than the minimum sum of \$ k \$ values \$ 2nmk \$ when \$ 1\le k\le m \$.

The sum of all those does not exceed \$ \lceil \frac {2nm}{1} \rceil m \$. Therefore if \$ a \$ is chosen to be \$ 2nm^2+1 \$, then the condition (1) is satisfied.

---

#### Minimum cost matrix permutation

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) (or [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output)? Obviously the latter would be more useful in <s>practice</s> code golf)

Given a matrix \$w\$ in \${\mathbb N_0}^{n\times n}\$, define the symmetric matrix \$d\$ in \${\mathbb N_0}^{n\times n}\$ by the formula \$d_{i,j}=\left| i-j \right|\$, find a permutation matrix \$P\$ such that the sum of elements in the matrix \$(P^{\mathsf T} \cdot w \cdot P ) \,\odot\,d\$ (where \$\odot\$ denotes the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))/element-wise product) is smallest.

The result will be the mean (TODO: median? mean of the 50% maximum? mean result/naive ratio?) of the score over these test cases, for as long as you can run your program.

Answer (score 1):

## (WIP) Settling the Lands of Codegolfia

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

---

The challenge controller will randomly generate a 200x200 map representing the terrain of the land

Your task is to write an AI whose goal is to have the largest population after 500 turns.

### Start

Each player begins with 1 cell claimed and a population of 100.

### Turns

On each turn, you have the opportunity to claim land cells. You can claim 1 cell per turn, plus 1 per 1000 population. Claimed cells must be orthogonally adjacent to a cell you already own. You cannot claim cells belonging to other players.

Turns happen simultaneously. In the event that two players attempt to claim the same cell, both players will lose 10 people from their population and neither player will claim the cell.

At the end of your turn, your population grows by 10% (rounded up), up to the maximum size your colony can support.

### Population Support

Without any land claimed, your colony can support up to 150 people.

Supporting larger populations requires claiming land. Each terrain type increases the amount by some amount. Combinations of terrain expand this further.

### Terrain

There are 4 terrain types:

- Plains

  - Supports 20 people by itself
  - Supports 5 per adjacent owned plains
- Forest

  - Supports 10 people by itself
  - Supports 5 per adjacent owned forest
  - Supports 50 additional people if there are at least 10 owned plains cells within 10 cells (Manhattan distance)
- Mountains

  - Supports 5 by itself
  - Supports 5 per owned plains within 15 cells
  - Supports 10 per owned forest within 5 cells
- Water

  - Each plains cell can support 500 additional people if it is within 5 cells of an owned water cell.
  - Each forest cell can support 200 additional people if it is within 10 cells of an owned water cell.

---

#### Alternative ideas for terrain

- Plains support raw population. Same as above
- Forest cells increase population support for all plains within 5 cells by a factor of 5% (stacks multiplicatively)
- For every water cell and 10 plains cells, reproduction rate increases by 1%
- Each mountain cell increases the range of each owned mountain and forest within 3 cells by 1. (stacks additively)

Comment: I was just thinking of something like this! (but different enough I can still do mine :p). Currently I don't see too many options for strategy other than comparing each orthagonal square each turn and picking the best.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms yeah. Maybe I should make each of the terrains more mechanically different. Maybe one increases reproduction rate, one expands synergy range, and another enhances the others.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, depending on how it's implemented. Maybe being close to water would let you claim extra land per turn near the body of water, sort of like exploration?

Answer (score 1):

## Score an approximation code challenge [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a list of inputs (strings) and their expected outputs (integers or floats)<sup>[1]</sup>, and a black-box program<sup>[2]</sup>, calculate the score using the following scoring system:

Let \$R_n\$ be the expected output of the \$n^{th}\$ input, let \$A_n\$ be the actual output given by the black-box program, and let \$ j \$ be the total number of input/output pairs. (All values are positive and non-zero)

Then the score is defined as:
$$S=\left\lceil L\times\max_{1\le i \le j}\left({\max\left(\frac{A_i}{R_i},\frac{R_i}{A_i}\right)^2}\right)\right\rceil$$
where \$L\$ is the length of the black-box program in bytes.

*Example:*

If the size of the program is \$100\$ bytes and the worst approximation is on the input "moon", where the program outputs \$1000\$ instead of the expected \$1737\$, then the score would be:

$$S=\left\lceil 100\times{\left(\frac{1737}{1000}\right)^2}\right\rceil=302$$

This system is taken shamelessly from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/177021) by [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/58563). [Here](https://tio.run/##ZVNhT9swEP3eX3GqELUhS5OmSdMxmNDUbkyUTS3bl1IJqzHgKXUyx0GtoH9qP2F/rLtzR8fggy@553fvni/OD3EvqrlRpX2ji0xuNmM4hum0Oal100v6SdTtzLxp83NdKisNQf0wJGQibG2QE6edyFG@GaHrqul14ihxwIUsba0lIt2k45CBMPYONaKek/guXUESxG53JAxmUdQPKPso9GohMypHE4RcKis06fdiR5dmXpsVyXddxQeR56qyBSGhQ87wPUy3vUdFgcVhL@o5J7UpSoF5nDgrl0ZZtx/FEeVf85qEwjBNHN2oirLEbX4S9UJicRomO18K816azmZHjcb03APf909hhrM08metjGStm6rFfSNFNlS5nKz0nLXambxvVzZTGrdsMbFG6VvG/arMlWWtK4IXomQajk/gUPOjxk1hFsKirIM0Fg3VUmasw/1SZAOdsTBA2kIskROgl7GPJQMxv2NsqsVCemBEpupq5oHmpPHQAJgXuipy6efFLSPSk1afwyE04S2uQ9i2ZgaFS/xScpgXmJ5O9YwTjanqQlwww@HxEQy8w/bwHpgRVhVYEkIbAg@ag/H4y7jJSbOUWuR2BU8U9qzLSNg7PPqSbd2ia9ek2YZXJKVfkvjvXyhHxF37f3roY0d3TwI4HBxAh@/GGXOOU4S/1k6A5rm/D2w7V4d6UOZCS/ctcGRIX@NqqBscxFBp/FuIjYZeDvj6So/E0oeXx997QP4zB2s6JqLbNutrZ@g/ocm8MBIr51LlbO/hfA3L1yrcSbvzO945HNBxuBNcN2ReyVcW8ead6XuRqwyvb1XnFq8ukjebMAgaSRIH9Egpxv0eRvwlKXZjwrcwhqhLYLIL0VMIUwrEC6kidFiHAumnXVxh8Ac) is his reference implementation.

---

[1]: You may take the inputs and outputs either zipped (`[(in1, out1), (in2, out2), ...]`), or not zipped (`([in1, in2, ...], [out1, out2, ...])`, with both lists of the same length), at your option.

[2]: You may take the black-box program as either:

- a [black-box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706), and its length in bytes, as two separate inputs
- a string of code to be evaluated, as one input (the length will not be given separately [unless necessary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262))

## Rules

- You may use any [sensible I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: (1) is it a problem if the program only support integers? (2) is it guaranteed that both values (actual and submission output) are strictly positive? The formula is not well defined when either value is zero.

Comment: @user202729 all values will be positive; the idea was that you can support integers or floats, whichever is easier

Comment: The "whichever is easier" part is currently not mentioned in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Stack half full or half empty? *(worldview of a programming language)*

Is the glass half full or half empty?
It's a common rethoric question to determine a person worldview, which can be optimistic or pessimistic based on the answer given.
If i were dealing with a machine i would probably ask "Is the stack half full or half empty?"
Let's try and see if programming languages have a worldview too.

Write a full program or a function which prints or returns one of "The stack is half full." or "The stack is half empty." when given as input the question "Is the stack half full or half empty?" but wait.. you have to provide a stack to be observed.. which stack you provide is up to you: input one or check an already existing stack.
Your solution will then output one of the two sentences mentioned above for a non empty / non full stack, your choice which one to print, just make sure your answer is as short as possible because this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).
For an empty stack it must produce the "empty" output while for a full stack "full".

## Survey

I will make a chart of the pessimistic Vs optimistic languages based on the half outputs.
If you find the same byte count for both choices you can provide both, in which case they will count on both sides of the chart, but you just can select one if you like.

### input

- A sentence in any reasonable method.
- The behavior is defined only for the question "Is the stack half full or half empty?" and exactly this.
- Indeed your solution can also completely ignore the input as long as it works with the specified input.
- Question mark is mandatory.

### output

- One of "The stack is half full." or "The stack is half empty.", for a non full / non empty stack.
- "full" or "empty" for a full stack or an empty stack respectively
- upper / lower case or a mix are fine.
- ending dot not mandatory.

## Rules

- Only the mentioned input allowed.
- Loopholes allowed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and the answer with the fewer bytes of source code wins.

Comment: This would be a really cool challenge, but the tasks are too similar. I doubt anything other than `print "The glass is half full"` will be competitive. Maybe add an additional thing they have to do, in addition to printing the text? As an example, for half empty, take a number of inputs and discard every second one. For half full, print every other fibonacci number.

Comment: So undefined behaviour is fine for all inputs that are not one of the two specific questions?

Comment: Your initial description only mentions one possible input, while your "input" section mentions both.

Comment: Thanks @Redwolf Programs ! To be honest I had this crazy idea but don't really knew how to make it interesting.. I ended developing it in the simplest and most obvious way.. Maybe I 'll change many things during the sandbox

Comment: @Adám yes for UB, for the input I'm sorry, my fault.. Initially I was using only one question but then decided it was reasonable to handle both combinations.. Gonna edit thanks!

Comment: @Redwolf Programs I changed a bit, I hope this stack thing will add some flavor without exiting the context, please let me know if you want to share some opinions

Comment: @Adám some changes.. If you have any opinions please let me know

Comment: @AZTECCO I still think half empty and half full should require doing different things. Currently I doubt anyone will pick half empty, because half full is shorter and there's no other difference.

Comment: @Redwolf Programs yeah that's true. I was wondering if languages with built in string compression, string methods or regex would compete the plain print"..answer.." method which should be around 25~30 of score but.. I don't know.. I just feel like a do this or that based on input is a different challenge but it seems to be the only way

Comment: @AZTECCO The concept of the answers choosing between two options is really cool and unique; the current options are just too similar. Maybe one thing that tests control flow, like a truth machine sort of thing, and one that tests input/output, like discarding every other output? The stack validating thing (where you have to print `empty` or `full`) feels kind of irrelevant to the cool part of the challenge. Having the input be the question isn't really necessary IMO; you could replace the input with something like a list of numbers (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and have the answers do one of two things with that list (totally up to you, although I'd recommend tasks that use different capabilities of the language, like one control flow and one math), then print `The glass is half (empty|full).`

Comment: @Redwolf Programs thanks for explaining your opinion, your insight are really important and I totally agree, I was losing the scope and your words got me back on track!

Answer (score 1):

## Bytewise look-and-say sequence [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The look-and-say sequence is a sequence which begins with `1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211`.
To get a term of the sequence from the previous, read the previous out literally:

`312211 => one three, one one, two twos,two ones => 13112221`

So the next term is `13112221`.

Given this javascript code (Node.js), which outputs the look-and-say sequence indefinitely, delimited by newlines:

```javascript
function nextTerm(x){
  return x.replace(/(.)\1*/g,z=>z.length+z[0])
}
function printUpTo(x){
  var str = '1';
  for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
    console.log(str);str = nextTerm(str);
  }
}
printUpTo(Infinity)
```

It will output a string that begins `1\n11\n21\n1211\n111221` etcetera. Your job is to write a function that takes a number as input and outputs that byte of the output string.

### Rules

You may output a different character for newline instead of \n, e.g. # or something.

### Scoring

Your program should be able to handle 100 million.

The first answer to handle 1e+18 correctly will receive a 100-rep bounty. This cannot be hard-coded.

Standard loopholes apply.

Test cases:

```
1 => \n
5 => 2
10 => 1
20 => 3
50 => 3
100 => 1
1000 => 1
100000 => 3
10000000 => 1
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest bytes wins.

Comment: Note that restricted-complexity means "solutions' time complexity must be polynomial in the input size" or something similar. "In a minute" means restricted-time, but then you have to specify the specification of your machine and test all solutions (although in most cases it will be obvious and you don't need to)

Comment: And an implementation of the naive algorithm in a low-overhead language (C++) would be able to do that as well.

Comment: @user202729 I'm not actually sure how to write this myself - notice that there isn't a testcase for 1 billion - that's because I couldn't figure out how to do an actually efficient version. Also, by 'In a minute', I mean on TIO. I'll add that.

Comment: And TIO isn't suitable for timing submissions (personally I think it's really suitable, but people don't agree.)

Comment: @user202729 What do you mean? Is it something to do with how busy the server is or similar?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/is-tio-acceptable-for-fastest-code-questions

Comment: @user202729 Ok, redoing the whole thing, since I don't want to install loads of different compilers/interpreters.

Comment: Ok, publishing.

Comment: Wait, I did warn you that a naive implementation in C++ would be able to do it.

Comment: Do you want to allow that?

Comment: Ok, 1e+12 should be fine.

Comment: Wait are you sure that there actually is a polynomial time solution?

Comment: I feel like there should be one, but I don't know. Never mind.

Comment: Actually there probably isn't since there's no way to calculate the nth term or length of nth term without calculating the previous. So never mind.

Comment: There probably is. (I didn't come up with one.)Although people could let their programs run for a month. 1e+18 is definitely safe, but might be a little too large for some polynomial approaches.

Comment: Is there? I'm pretty sure you can compress the data somehow, but didn't figure out the exact details.

Comment: What do you mean compress the data?

Comment: Just think it might be possible to speed up the program somehow. // That having said you can post the challenge with 1e18 and see if any interesting solution appears. There are some really smart users on this site.

Comment: Could you step through an example? I'm not sure what logic this is following.

Comment: Never mind my last comment, though I think this would benefit from an inline explanation of the look and say sequence and describe it as having a delimiter (`\n` in this case). I am tempted to say that this a duplicate, but it appears that this challenge indexing a particular character in the sequence makes this distinct from the basic challenge.

Comment: @user202729 I modified it so the naive algorithm in most languages should be able to do it, but added a 100-rep bounty for anyone who manages to handle 1e+18. Final opinion before I publish please?

Comment: Looks okay, but it would be a duplicate if it doesn't require answers to be fast, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Self improving program

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

In this challenge you will write a program or function which when run will output a faster solution to this challenge.

Formally speaking: you will write a program or function, \$T_0\$, which takes an integer \$x\$ as input and outputs a program or function (in the same language), \$T_1\$, which is itself a valid solution to this challenge, such that there exists a function \$f\$ where \$T_1\$ is in the time complexity class \$O\left(f\right)\$,  but \$T_0\$ is not.  That is to say the output program must have a strictly faster asymptotic time complexity.

Note that since \$T_1\$ must be a valid solution to the challenge it must output a program or function \$T_2\$ which is even faster, and so on and so forth, creating an infinite chain each faster than the last.

Answers will be scored by their length in bytes with fewer being better.

---

## Precision

In keeping with the tradition of this site, and to remain inclusive: The order notation of a function will be assumed to be measured by *the algorithm implemented* by your answer.  Thus we will pretend not to notice the behavior of your actual program for inputs out of the range of your language's numeric type.

However that being said, in order to ensure that you are actually changing the algorithm at every step, for constants initialized in your program this leniency is not given.  e.g. If you use a double precision floating point `1.0000000000000001` is equal to `1.0`. So if your method relies on an increasing or decreasing constant embedded in the program you should be careful that the algorithm actually changes.

Simply put for \$T_n(x)\$ you are forgiven for errors arising from very large \$x\$, but not from very large \$n\$.

Comment: (which is the same thing is \$T_0\in o(T_1) \$.)

Comment: How is this possible? You'd need to get faster and faster, and even if you do it exponentially, you can't change the speed by tiny fractions of a second each time. Please explain, very confused.

Comment: And what prevents programs from doing `for i in range(int(n**1.00001)): pass`?

Comment: Thinking about it again, since programs can simply run a loop to have any asymptotic complexity (>= complexity to parse input), it's not that hard. And you could just ask programs to print out an always-decreasing floating point value plus the new program.

Comment: @user202729 But the always-decreasing float is the problem here, because eventually it will get too small to be distinguished by the language from 0.

Comment: @Ausername An easier way to have it constantly decreasing is to have O(n^2) -> O(n log(n)) -> O(n log(log(n))) -> O(n log(log(log(n)))) etc.  This approaches O(n) from above and remains distinguishable for really large inputs, without requiring anything finicky about precision.

Comment: @user202729 Do the precision rules address your comments?

Comment: It means that programs doing things like (Python) `n=1000000000000000000000000000000; for i in range(int(input())**(1+1/n): pass` and `(1+1/n)` evaluates to `1` (because of IEEE754, even though the value of `n` is stored exactly) will fail?

Comment: @user202729 Yes.  Precision rules are always pretty non-concrete and non-objective.  I think it is best to not try to push at the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

*Posted at [Convert Gemtext to HTML](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220044/convert-gemtext-to-html) but moved here to discuss*

[Gemtext](https://communitywiki.org/wiki/GemText) is a very simple markup format used by the alternative web protocol Gemini. Write a Gemtext to HTML converter.

From the Wiki:

> A line of text is a paragraph, to be wrapped by the client. It is is
> independent from the  lines coming before or after it.
>
> A list item starts with an asterisk and a space. Again, the rest of
> the line is the line item, to be wrapped by the client.
>
> A heading starts with one, two, or three number signs and a space. The
> rest of the line is the heading.
>
> A link is never an inline link like it is for HTML: it’s simply a line
> starting with an equal-sign and a greater-than sign: “⇒”, a space, an
> URI, and some text. It could be formatted like a list item, or like a
> paragraph. Relative URIs are explicitly allowed.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # This is a heading 
> This is the first paragraph.
> * a list item
> * another list item 
> This is the second paragraph.
> => http://example.org/ Absolute URI
> => //example.org/ No scheme URI
> => /robots.txt Just a path URI
> => GemText a page link
> ```

This should produce this HTML tree (just the equivalent tree, not the exact formatting):

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph.</p>
<ul>
<li>a list item</li>
<li>another list item</li>
</ul>
<p>This is the second paragraph.</p>
<a href="http://example.org/">Absolute URI</a>
<a href="//example.org/">No scheme URI</a>
<a href="/robots.txt">Just a path URI</a>
<a href="GemText">a page link</a>
```

HTML in the text must be escaped, e.g `paragraph <p> is cool` becomes `<p>paragraph &ltp&gt is cool</p>`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Can you clarify "whitespace ... doesn't matter"?

Comment: @Wezl edited question

Comment: What parts of HTML do we need to handle? Can we convert every character (even unreserved ones like `A`) to its entity number? Is the input guaranteed to be ASCII only or do we need to handle other characters? I don't know Gemtext well enough to ask about it, but are there escape characters or something that would allow mapping, say, to HTML: `<p># A paragraph</p>`?

Answer (score 1):

## Let's rise higher!

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining), [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number), [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

*(I am posting this challenge in sandbox because this kind of exceptional challenges are often closed, and then downvoted to oblivion, so I want to get your feedback and with kind help you fix the specifications in this challenge, and make it interesting, Thanks!)*

---

## Challenge

The main objective of the challenge is pretty simple, this is an answer chaining contest, where you have to serially print numbers from 1. That means User 1's answer will print `1`, then User 2's answer will print `2` and so on. But there are some rules to make the contest tougher.

## Rules

- **You can't use the characters of the source code used in the previous answer.**
- **Each answer cannot use more than 12 distinct bytes.**
- Use of comments in your code is disallowed.
- You cannot post 2 answers in a row, let me explain, suppose you have written answer no. 5, now you cannot write answer no. 6, you have to wait someone to post a valid answer no. 6 (That prints `6` without using characters in answer no. 5), and after that you can write a valid answer no. 7 following the rules.
- Program cannot take input or access internet.
- Standard loopholes apply.

## Scoring criterion

**This is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so there is a custom objective scoring criteria. Try to make your score higher.**

- Each answer's initial score is 1. (Only chain beginning answer has score 0).
- For each distinct byte you use, your score is increased by the number of distinct bytes. That means if your number of distinct bytes is `6`, then your score increases by `1+2+3+4+5+6`, and if your number of distinct bytes is `7`, then your score increases by `1+2+3+4+5+6+7` and so on.
- You have to calculate distinct byte difference with the previous answer, and add/subtract score using the 2nd rule. So if byte difference is `3` then you will get a `+1+2+3` score, or if `-3` (Previous answer has 3 more distinct bytes than yours), then `-1-2-3`.
- For first 40 bytes you will get a `0.15` score, but from then you have to minus `0.5` score. An example if your score has total 45 bytes then your score bonus will be `(40*0.15)-(5*0.5)=6-2.5=3.5`, so you have to add `+3.5` to your score. (The score criteria is to encourage medium length smart answers.)

A total example:

Suppose,

- Your previous answer has 4 distinct bytes, and a total of 20 bytes
- Your answer has 7 distinct bytes, and a total of 56 bytes

So your score will be:

```
Distinct byte difference: (7-4)=3
Total score: 1+(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)+(1+2+3)+(40*0.15)-(16*0.5)=33
```

So you get a score of `33` for this condition.

## Answer format

```
# Answer Number. Language Name, x Bytes, y Distinct bytes, Score: Z

    source code

(TIO/Any other interpreter link) -> Not required, but preferred
```

**example**

```
1. Powershell, x Bytes, y Distinct Bytes, Score: Z

......
```

## Winning criterion

**Winner will be determined after 30 days, winner is determined by total score. But users are welcome to continue the chain after that!**

Suppose you have three answers with score `33,16,78` then your total score will be `33+16+78=127`.

And there is two special prizes from me after 30 days:

- +150 bounty for the winner.
- +50  bounty for the single answer with highest score! (Such as man of the match in Cricket)

## Chain beginning answer:

---

## 1. [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 1 byte, 1 distinct byte, Score: 0

```powershell
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3/D/fwA)

---

## Meta

- Are all rules clear?
- Please improve the scoring criterion and rules. (Especially please improve the second rule, I am not very sure about that.)
- Please make me a javascript snippet for leaderboard, to sort users by their total score.
- Any other feedback please.

Comment: There are a bunch of small things that could be clarified (particularly the scoring), but I think there is a larger problem you should try to fix first. Answer-chaining challenges rely on the task becoming more difficult as more answers are posted, but since you are only restricted by the previous response getting an optimal score will probably not be difficult until the number of answers is very large (much larger than 100). If you fix this, then the problem becomes that if finding a good answer is difficult, posting for more score becomes a race, which usually isn't fun.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman if the number of answers are large, then you would sort the question by active. What are the other problems please say.

Comment: The number of answers being large isn't the problem. Please re-read my comment - it is talking about how the challenge isn't a good answer-chaining challenge because the approach for each link in the chain is too similar. Try writing what you think the next solution would be, and the one after that, and I think you will start to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Hello, Permutations!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220662/hello-permutations)

Comment: [tag:restricted-source] or [tag:source-layout]

Comment: If you want do disallow trivial answers that use `quit` or comments or something, you could require all 3 programs to be [irreducible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824). However, I think it might not be as interesting like that, because it would then just be the same as all the existing irreducible [tag:restricted-source] challenges. It's still an interesting challenge to optimise the length of three similar programs with the same charset. Extra feedback: I'd recommend changing `Hello, World!` to another string because many languages have Hello World built-ins.

Comment: Also, maybe specify that functions are allowed as well as programs, according to our [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447). And can you clarify whether the Hello World has to include the quotes?

Comment: @pxeger Thanks, I have updated my post and I agree that the irreducible rule is not needed. Even a "trivial" answer seems challenging to arrive at. About the string, maybe I can change it to `"Hello, Permutations!"` which also goes with the challenge title, but I am unsure if I should.

Comment: `Hello, Permutations!` sounds fine - I think it would be a good idea. Again, can you clarify whether you want the double quotes around `"Hello, Permutations!"` to be outputted literally or not?

Comment: @pxeger Changed it, and its clarified now.

Answer (score 1):

## Find the Best Set of Adapters

Moved here: [Find the Best Set of Adapters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220911/find-the-best-set-of-adapters)

Comment: This reminds me of one of the 2020 AoC challenges, don't remember exactly what the task was but it had a similar premise. (Also there's no need to disallow standard loopholes explicitly, they're disallowed by default :p)

Comment: It was "Day 10: Adapter Array" but that was about finding the number of ways to reach the result and the adapters were a bit different.

Comment: This looks like it'll be a fun challenge, although I'd be careful to look around because there might be a duplicate with an entirely different name/background that involves doing the exact same thing.

Comment: May it contains adapter from A -> A? Although it would be not useful. It could be included in testcases. (make sure implementation will not fall into infinity loop in such case.) Will it possible 0 adapter is required (Same type for both computer and phone already)? If so, add another testcase for it.

Comment: Also, is it possible that part of given graph is not connected to computer / phone types. For example, `A, C; A->B; B->C; X->Y; Y->Z`.

Comment: Current testcases does not contains cycle. It would be helpful to include one: `A, C; A->B; B->C; C->A` for example.

Comment: Your description says "Unfortunately, none of them can go straight from my phone to my computer". but your last testcase output 1. One of them should be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, @tsh for the great feedback. I have edited the question with your suggestions in mind.

Comment: 2nd test case seems incorrect.

Comment: @tsh thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Uppercase JSON member names

Given a single valid [JSON](https://json.org) value, uppercase all member names. That is, you must also return valid JSON that encodes an equivalent value, except that all names of members in all objects, have been converted to uppercase according to one of the Unicode methods (simple or full).

**Details:**

- The given value can be null, a number, a string, an array, or an object. There may therefore not be any names to convert, but such names can also "hide" as elements/members of arrays/objects in arrays/objects, …
- Dictionaries are considered unordered.
- Names and strings will only encode ASCII.
- Keys will be unique, even after case conversion.
- Floating point imprecision is tolerated.

### Example input A

```json
["a\":",{"b":"c"}]
```

#### Example outputs

```json
["a\":",{"B":"c"}]
```

```json
[
  "a\":",
  {
    "B" : "c"
  }
]
```

### Example input B

```json
{"h\u0065re":
"are'=",    "be"
:{"dra\u0000gons":true,"b\\e\"ar\ns":"two"},"\t":[1e-0,null,3e+2
,  {"":""} ,{
},
"name\":\"value",[false,[],[[]]]]}
```

#### Example outputs

```json
{                      
 "BE": {               
  "B\\E\"AR\nS": "two",
  "DRA\u0000GONS": true
 },                    
 "HERE": "are'=",      
 "\t": [1,             
  null,                
  300,                 
  {                    
   "": ""              
  },                   
  {                    
  },                   
  "name\":\"value",    
  [false,              
   [],                 
   [[]]]]              
}
```

```json
{"BE":{"B\\E\"AR\nS":"two","DRA\u0000GONS":true},"HERE":"are'=","\t":[1,null,300,{"":""},{},"name\":\"value",[false,[],[[]]]]}
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion)

Comment: Is order of keys in a dictionary matters? For example, input `{"b":0,"a":0}`, may I output `{"A":0,"B":0}`? Will there be any duplicate object keys? For example, is `{"a":1,"a":2}` a valid input? ECMA-404 allow duplicate keys, but RFC 8259 disallow it. For above input, may I output `{"A":2}` only? What about duplicate keys after conversion? For example, is input `{"a":1,"A":2}`valid? And what should I output?

Comment: @tsh How is this?

Comment: May I assume keys only contains characters in range U+0020~U+00FE? For example, are keys like `{"großes":1,"æða":2,"ｈｅｌｌｏ":3,"βῆτα":4}` invalid?

Comment: @tsh non-ASCII keys are literally mentioned in the bullet points and included in the example case.

Comment: May I output `DRA\u0000GᎤNSS` for `dra\u0000gꭴnß`instead of `DRA\u0000GᎤNß`?

Comment: @tsh Silly me for not thinking of the various methods. Addressed.

Comment: @tsh All answered: 1: "Dictionaries are unordered." 2: "Keys will be unique" 3: "Keys will be unique, even after case conversion."

Comment: May I use different unicode normalization from inputs? For example, Input `{"e\u0301":1}`, may I output `{"\u00c9":1}`? And for input `{"\u00e9":1}`, may I output `{"E\u0301":1}`?

Comment: @tsh Good point. Addressed now. Do you think it would be an improvement to restrict input to ASCII only?

Comment: Try to support uppercase for non-ASCII would simply require submission in some languages with such a built-in support. And as code-golf context, no one would likely to handle it manually. So restrict it to ASCII only would be helpful to let more languages involved.

Comment: @tsh Done. How is this?

Comment: You are still using "ꭴ" in it. Also suggest testcases with object in array: `{"extra":[0, {"key":[[[{"inner":{}}]]]}]}`

Comment: @tsh Did you refresh? I don't see any `"ꭴ"`. There are objects in the `"\t"` array.

Comment: Will input always be a json object (dictionary)? For example, another testcase `["a",{"b":"c"}]`, `null`, And maybe it need more testcases. And if I try to parse the JSON string first, may floating point errors allowed? For example, input `{"a":[17706675576718736274, 300223795848957673199326286566205161047]}`, may I output `{"A":[17706675576718735000,3.0022379584895768e+38]}`

Comment: @tsh Good questions. Should all be addressed now.

Comment: example input A seems malformed.You write `|` instead of `\​` in it.

Comment: @tsh Nicely spotted. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [I ain't no Fortunate sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220713/i-aint-no-fortunate-sum)

Answer (score 1):

### [Minimally Making Change](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220864)

Comment: What is expected output for 10? To my understanding, it should be 0010, but you give 5100. Am I misunderstand something?

Comment: @tsh They have to be able to make all cents 1-10 with the coins. So they need 5 pennies for making 1-4 and the nickel to make 9. Hopefully clarified a bit

Answer (score 1):

## Fortuitous Numbers

[Four is Magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230978/code-golf-four-is-magic) is a very interesting math game.

1. We start out with a number: 1
2. We spell it into English: “one”
3. We find the sum of the letters: 3
4. Go back to step 2, until the game ends at “4”

The reason “4” is Magic, is that “Four” has 4 letters, and no other number has this property.

---

#### Fortuitous Numbers

In this game, I’m making one change.

1. Take for example the number: 24.
2. Write it out in English: “twenty four”
3. Note that there are 2 words
4. Take the *product* of the word lengths
5. 24 - “twenty four” - `6 * 4` = 24

4 and 24 are Fortuitous Numbers. Are there any more?

---

#### The challenge

Your challenge is to create a piece of code that will generate all Fortuitous Numbers.

Specifically:

1. Solutions should be found by the program, not chached by you.
2. We never say, “one hundred ***and*** one”. Exclude the “and”
3. The only output should contain a comma separated list of only the solutions:

```
4,
24,
n,
m,
```

4. The code should have no limit as to how large the number can go. If you have trouble finding names, used the ones mentions [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers). This will take you smoothly to 10<sup>3003</sup> and beyond.
5. Hint: Look at the sequence, [A058230](https://oeis.org/A058230).

---

#### Bonus!

1. Program generates the first 9 solutions relatively quickly (under 5 minutes time.)
2. Program also finds Fortuitous Numbers if type `a -> b -> ... -> a` instead of just `a -> a`

Answer (score 1):

## [What's missing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230271/whats-missing-aka-the-vanilla-set-difference-challenge)

Comment: This is probably too easy

Comment: Some languages may have built-in Bag / MultiSet / Counter collection type. And a simple `-` operate or something similar may get correct result. Will you allow answers use such type of values as input / output?

Comment: @tsh I guess?   It doesn't really make a difference for the languages that have creative solutions. It's code-golf, which means answers generally don't get accepted.

Comment: ruby does have `array-array`, but it wont work for arrays with similar items missing. I feel this is easy, but it can work as a codegolf challenge

Comment: @EliteDaMyth Honestly, I'm really surprised this doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

### ROT47(code) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher)[source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

[ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) is a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) where every letter is replaced by the 13th letter that follows it in the alphabet.

Every letter and its counterpart:

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m |

[ROT47](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-47-cipher) is a deritave of ROT13 which includes all the [ASCII printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) except space. Rot47 substitutes every character with the 47th character that follows it in the ASCII range.
Every character and its counterpart:

| ! | " | # | $ | % | & | ' | ( | ) | * | + | , | - | . | / | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | : | ; | < | = | > | ? | @ | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | [ | \ | ] | ^ | _ | ` | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | { | | | } | ~ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | [ | \ | ] | ^ | _ | ` | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | { | | | } | ~ | ! | " | # | $ | % | & | ' | ( | ) | * | + | , | - | . | / | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | : | ; | < | = | > | ? | @ | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |

**I ROT47( your code) and you ROT47( the output)**

- *Your code is supposed to at least output 1 character within the [33,126] ASCII range.*
- *When ROT47 is applied on your code, the output should also be ROT47 of the previous output*
- *solve in the fewest bytes possible*

Below a ROT47 converter taken from [decode](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-47-cipher)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var editor = CodeMirror(input, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    mode: 'javascript',
    theme: 'monokai'
});
editor.setSize(900, 100);
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
  editor.setValue(rot47(editor.getValue()));
}


//implementation below from https://www.dcode.fr/rot-47-cipher
// Javascript
function rot47(x){
 var s='';
 for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  var j=x.charCodeAt(i);
  if((j>=33)&&(j<=126)){
   s+=String.fromCharCode(33+((j+14)%94));
  }
  else {
   s+=String.fromCharCode(j);
  }
 }
 return s;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/codemirror.min.css" integrity="sha512-xIf9AdJauwKIVtrVRZ0i4nHP61Ogx9fSRAkCLecmE2dL/U8ioWpDvFCAy4dcfecN72HHB9+7FfQj3aiO68aaaw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/codemirror.min.js" integrity="sha512-hc0zo04EIwTzKLvp2eycDTeIUuvoGYYmFIjYx7DmfgQeZPC5N27sPG2wEQPq8d8fCTwuguLrI1ffatqxyTbHJw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/theme/monokai.min.css" integrity="sha512-R6PH4vSzF2Yxjdvb2p2FA06yWul+U0PDDav4b/od/oXf9Iw37zl10plvwOXelrjV2Ai7Eo3vyHeyFUjhXdBCVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body style="background-color:#333333
">
<div id="input">
</div></br>
<button id="button" style="background-color: #17202a
;color:white">ROT47</button>
</body>
```

---

#### Meta questions:

- Is it an interesting challenge?
- Is the explanation clear?
- suggestion for a title.

Comment: why does it look normal in edit mode but not in the result .

Comment: Fixed the formatting. SE doesn't show tables unless they have an empty line before and after them

Comment: so valid answers and their input must be printable ASCII? Or should it ignore anything not printable?

Comment: It looks like the reference implementation leaves non-printable characters and space alone. It would be helpful to specify that.

Comment: Well, if you look on main, this is a alternate of an alternate of a rip-off of a rip-off of a rip-off of a rip-off of a rip-off of a rip-off. (see [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221225/i-rot-13-the-source-code-you-rot-19-the-output)). Which is not to say it's a bad challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [To count the sum of all Unicode characters of a given input under an interesting constraint](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221321/101710)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for using the sandbox! Can you confirm that answering with a normal (base-10) number is OK?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, edited accordingly- Final answer can to be calculated in any base (either Hexadecimal, or base-10 or binary as per the program) no need to convert back.

Comment: I know you've posted this already, but generally I recommend leaving challenges in the sandbox for a week.

Comment: Ohk. I will remember it from the next time. thanks a lot

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## Sum of two squares

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given an integer \$n\$, determine whether \$n\$ can be expressed as the sum of two square numbers, that is \$\exists a,b\in\mathbb Z|n=a^2+b^2\$.

```
   0 -> truthy
   1 -> truthy
   2 -> truthy
   3 -> falsy
   4 -> truthy
   5 -> truthy
   6 -> falsy
   7 -> falsy
  11 -> falsy
9997 -> truthy
9999 -> falsy
```

Relevant OEIS sequences:

- [A001481](https://oeis.org/A001481) - should return truthy
- [A022544](https://oeis.org/A022544) - should return falsy

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer as measured in bytes wins.

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64812/count-sums-of-two-squares), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28169/four-squares-together).

Comment: This is a subset of [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64812/68942).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yes, and I have that listed as a related problem. There's actually another method of solving this problem involving prime factors which doesn't work for that one, so I'm hoping that's novel enough to warrant a separate challenge.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the link. And yes, I don't think it'd be a duplicate here; I do agree that there will probably be unique approaches to this specific problem.

Comment: A couple [answers here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64812/count-sums-of-two-squares) used the prime-factorization approach, and a few used the approach of counting divisors of the form 4k+1 and 4k+3 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## Irreducible Rube Goldberg Sort (WIP)

[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

---

You are given a list containing at least 10 integers. You must sort them in the most complicated and roundabout way possible.

Your task is to write \$n\$ programs (or functions) which, when combined in a specific constant sequence (specifically, feeding the output of the current step into the input of the next step), result in a sorted version of the original list. This sequence of programs should be set up in such a way that the system will not work if any subset of steps is removed. (for example, compressing and decompressing the stream, roundabout encryption that cancels itself out, etc...)

Your score is \$n\$. Highest score wins.

### Rules, Clarifications, and Notes

- Standard rules and loopholes apply
- Any method of I/O is fair game. It does not need to be consistent across all programs/functions.
- You may use any number of programming languages to solve the problem.
- It should not take an unreasonably long time to sort a list of up to 1000 elements using your system of programs. It should be reasonable to run it from start to finish during a lunch break (30 minutes)
- Lists can contain any integer from -999,999,999 to 999,999,999, inclusive, and may contain indistinguishable duplicates.
- Your system of programs should work for lists of any size if given enough time and space.

Comment: What is there to put an upper bound on the size, other than irreducibility? I'm almost certain there's a way to get an infinite score pretty trivially.

Comment: I suspect there's a way to have an arbitrarily complicated sequence of programs as well and I'm not quite sure how to limit that, aside from performance (the 30 minute rule)

Comment: Does the process have to be deterministic (e.g. no implementation of bogosort)? I think your rules imply that, but it might be good to state explicitly.

Comment: Throwing in a randomizer step probably wouldn't be irreducible.

Comment: So a recursive approach (e.g. one similar to Stooge sort) is a no-starter?

Comment: @Bubbler feeding a step's output into its own input is not allowed, so yes, that probably wouldn't work. Basically, the idea is that you could run this as a bash pipeline and no matter what the input sequence is, you wouldn't be able to remove any subset of steps and have it still work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dominate a zero-sum game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222839/dominate-a-zero-sum-game)

Answer (score 1):

[Shrinking Triangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223701/)

Answer (score 1):

Write a rectangular code that takes a rectangular input and output it. If the code is repeated horizonally and vertically for times, output the input rectangular repeated for same amount of times.

Take an example, if your submission is

```
CODE
HERE
```

, then program

```
CODECODECODECODE
HEREHEREHEREHERE
CODECODECODECODE
HEREHEREHEREHERE
```

inputting

```
01
23
45
```

should output

```
01010101
23232323
45454545
01010101
23232323
45454545
```

Comment: Nice one. But I didn't understand if there is s specific output.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a C program that is less than 120 characters the produces the most ASM possible.**

This limit does not include the def of main, or including headers. If a function is called the chars in the function count toward limit. The same goes for macros. The compiler used will be GCC 10.2 -O3 targeting x86-64.

The code conforms to these parameters and produces the most instructions wins.

I have a few questions regarding this. Is the character limit too limiting? Is the choice of compiler a good one? Is the optimization level being -O3 a good idea? Please share any other thoughts you have.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t see a reason to limit the size of the program. You could score based on Assembly Instructions per Source Byte to encourage small code sizes without excluding a clever 121 byte solution. I also don’t think the rules around #include headers and counting the size of any functions called are clear (How many characters are in `printf`?). You could ban explicit #includes but allow implicit function declarations as long as the compiler accepts them.

Comment: Should printf be 6 chars or should it be the size of the definition of the function printf? I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

## Find the traitor [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) (WIP)

In this challenge, the cops are the robbers/moles and the robbers are the cops/investigators.

### Cops

Cops will write a program that will output one of the following strings:

- "Hello World!"
- "Totally not evil stuff"
- "Good morning"
- "Innocent things"

However, when `n` specific characters are removed, where `0 < n < length of cop's program`, the resulting program should output one of the following strings:

- "Bye World!"
- "Top secret stuff"
- "Evil things"
- "Horrible morning"

Cops will reveal the original program and `n`, but not the resulting program. They will also reveal the 2 strings that must be outputted by the original and transformed programs.

A cop's score is \$\binom n r\$, or \$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\$, where \$r\$ is the size of the cop's program and \$n\$ is the number of characters to be deleted. The lower the score, the better.

#### Rules

- The original and transformed program may output in different ways, as long as the cop specifies what they are.
- The characters to be deleted do not have to be adjacent.

### Robbers

Robbers must find a way to make the cop's program output the chosen 2nd string by removing any `n` characters (not necessarily the same as the cop's).

### Example cop

Python, n = 1

```
a = ["Totally not evil stuff", "Hello World!"][01]
print(a)
```

The original string is "Hello World!", and the transformed program prints "Totally not evil stuff".

### Example robber

Python, cracks [Foobar's answer](https://rr.noordstar.me/18b15a7f)

```
a = ["Totally not evil stuff", "Hello World!"][0]
print(a)
```

Deleting the `1` at the end of the first line prints the target string.

### Questions for Meta:

- Which original and transformed strings should I use?
- Is this a duplicate?

Comment: This could be kind of difficult to write a cop for that doesn't just rely on someone brute forcing it

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Hmm, you're right. I guess just saying "pls don't brute force" wouldn't work. Maybe instead of a string, submissions could implement a mathematical function? You wouldn't be able to verify, say, cosine using just brute force.

Comment: That could be really cool actually. If you had a variety of ones like `sqrt`, `tan`, factorial, sum of proper divisors, and so on it would be a lot of fun.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Only problem would be that there wouldn't be any more traitors to root out :( I made the challenge just for the title

Answer (score 1):

## KotH: Assembly Anarchy

Draft. Just posting this so I don't forget I had this idea. Feel free to suggest improvements to the general idea here.

Basically, there would be a computer with memory and a processor. Programs would be submitted in a custom assembly language, and they would try to run a function (their flag) as many times as possible. They could try to interfere with other programs, by doing things like replacing the pointer to another bot's flag with their own, or preventing other bots from being run.

Comment: I like the concept. It needs a lot of fleshing out, though.

Answer (score 1):

## Poor Man's DRM

Write a program that only prints `Welcome` at the first execution and first execution only. All executions after the first execution should only print `Where money`.

Anything is allowed as long as the following condition is met: An execution ends after the program exits. So the second execution can only start after the first execution exits completely.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Reason for the condition: to prevent submissions that linger around in the memory and keep a runtime counter.

Comment: any things that are disallowed? E.g. can a program write to its source file?

Comment: @Wezl no, actually that's what I originally had in mind when writing this, but I decided to keep all the options open. -- edit for clarification: by "no", I meant it is allowed.

Comment: @goodguy Nice challenge. You may want to look at [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13697/what-does-standard-loopholes-apply-mean) and [main article](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cooperative counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223202/cooperative-counting)

Comment: looks like a nice challenge

Comment: I can't wait to code a bot for this challenge!

Comment: @math patience :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Basic Typescript Types](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223463/16484)

Comment: suggested testcase: `string | string`, `number & number`

Comment: @tsh I just posted the question, thanks for the suggestion, I'll add the testcases there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Matching to Homologous group](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223539/matching-homologous-groups)

Comment: 1. The underscore doesn't really seem necessary to me since there can't be any other syntax. 2. Can we assume the input will always be one of those categories? If not, add some test cases, and clarify the possible elements/other syntax that might be in the input. 3. Add [tag:classification] tag? 4. Will you allow output as any 6 distinct values (not saying it has to be, but some challenges do allow this to remove the part of compressing some strings), or does it have to be those strings? If so, do they need to be capitalised exactly like that?

Comment: @pxeger the input is guaranteed to be in 6 categories. Classification tag added. About the underscore i'll think later. And output needs to be exactly capitalized like in question. Thanks!

Comment: Also maybe add some more test cases with larger numbers (more than 1 digit)? And clarify what integer syntax is allowed (areleading zeroes allowed, can the number be <2)?

Answer (score 1):

## Exchange of money in least notes

Suppose A and B are two good friends. A has borrowed \$n\$ dollar from B. Now B wants the money back from A and A is also ready to give it. But the problem is A has only \$x\$ dollar notes and B has \$y\$ dollar notes. They both want to keep the number of notes in exchange as low as possible.

As an example if \$n=37\$, \$x=5\$ and \$y=2\$, then the least amount of notes in exchange will be nine 5 dollar noted from A then four 2 dollar notes from B will make 37. This solution is found through brute forcing with a python program.

Here in the challenge your input will be values of \$n, x, y\$ and output should be the least of amount of notes as possible for A, B. A will give notes first and B later. Input and output seperator can be anything, no leading zeros in input numbers, no negative numbers in input. Standard loopholes apply and shortest code wins.

**Test Cases**

```
37 5 2 -> 9 4
89 3 8 -> 35 8
100 12 7 -> 13 8
```

Comment: I'm almost certain there's a closed form solution to this, and if not one that's very close to closed form.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the given values of \$n\$, \$x\$ and \$y\$ lead to a valid solution? E.g. there's no solution for \$n=21\$, \$x=6\$, \$y=4\$.

Comment: @Delfad0r input is guaranteed to valid

Answer (score 1):

## [Posted ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224153/help-me-get-the-day-of-the-week-correct)

Comment: So this is just `abs(x-y)`, since I can just represent the days using integers? Doesn't seem very interesting

Comment: I think restricting the input to being one of the 7 days (maybe in whatever consistent case answers want) would be a better version of this

Comment: Won't this be simple `(x-y+7)%7`?

Answer (score 1):

## It seems \$2^n\$?

Let \$a_0=1\$ and \$a_{i+1}=1+\sum_{j=0}^ia_i\$, then \$a_i=2^i\$, which is no fun.

Now we reverse half of the value, \$a_{i+1}=L(1+\sum_{j=0}^ia_i)\$ for odd \$i\$, where \$L\$ reverse the number, e.g. 15=>51, 1230=>321.

Solve \$a_i\$. You can choose 1-index, or reverse each output(output \$L(a_i)\$).

First elements

```
1,2,4,8,16,23,55,11,121,242,484,869,1837,4763,8437,47861,64735,74921,204391,287804,696586,2713931,4107103,6024128,14238334,86667482,115144150,3882032,234170332,466043864,934384528,6509678681,8378447737,47459865761,64216761235,74225334821,202658857291,285417713504,690735428086,2716580741831,4098051598003,6006913016918,14203016212924,84852423060482,113258455486330,66279019615622,292795930588282,465671168195585,1051263029372149,8924478506252012,11027004564996310,2629992190045022,24684001320037642,48257004620086394,97625007260161678,653323025410052591,848573039930375947,4981570689706417961,6678716769567169855,1793343193533475331,15150776732667815041,28003653356435510303,58305206821771140385,77082245346314016611,193692658989856297381,267495217979713583783,654880535959426178545,907532588191701679031,2217293660110554036121,2422708011220237854344,6857295331441345926586,27135819628826609541731,40850410291709301394903,60898720681438502800718,142599541264857105590524,840181112417925280991582,1125380194947639492172630,625434898725989830670522,2876195288621268815015782,4651300367352427750932575,10403690944594965380964139,87282916703998198818370802,108090298593188129580299080,61895061952673681795081612,278075659139049940955679772,445953119188990872813151655,1002104437467090754724511199,8932209449051814394788024002,10936418323985995904237046400,829047480819917974663827812,22701884128791909783137920612,42214857266591838575286730454,87618625524175658141562571678,653341521382613153840152732571,828578772430964470123277875927,4581575556420498291684457517561,6238733101282427231931013269415,3883562026836445846520266477421
```

Not found on OEIS

Comment: 1) You should make it clear whether we need to print the \$i\$'th term, or the first \$i\$ terms or we can print the infinite sequence. Usually challenges like these allow all of these options. 2) Can you clarify what does "reverse each output" mean? So instead of \$a_i\$, the solutions can also print reverse of it?  3) There also needs to be a winning criterion.

Answer (score 1):

## Meta-golf Branch integers without alphanumeric characters [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)

Recently I created a new programming language, [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang) (name thanks to caird coinheringaahing). Representing numbers is pretty easy (actually, trivial; you can just enter the number and it will set the value of the current node to that number).

However, until a recent revision, you could only enter one digit, and larger numbers needed to be generated by combining digits with various operations. This led me to think of this challenge - given any integer, you can represent it without needing the digits, actually.

### Branch Specifications

Branch operates on a binary tree. Initially, there is just one node with a `0` as its value. Nodes hold `long long int`s. Any node that's created (unless otherwise specified) has a `0` initially.

Without the digits, here are the relevant instructions (you can also check them out on the [wiki page](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/wiki/Instructions)):

#### Unary Operators

`!` - logical NOT; set the value to `1` if it's `0` and `0` otherwise
`~` - bitwise NOT / complement; flip the bits; this is equivalent to `-1 - x`
`_` - negate; set the value to `-x`
`{` - decrement
`}` - increment

#### Binary Operators

`+`, `-`, `*`, `:`, `%`, `'`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `&`, and `|` are add, subtract, multiply, integer divide, modulo (keeps the sign of the right argument), exponentiation, strict less than (`1` is true, `0` is false), equality, strict greater than, bitwise AND, and bitwise OR, respectively.

Division and modulo give `0` if the right argument is `0`. The left and right arguments are the left and right children. Note that Branch will read from STDIN if these are missing, instead of initializing to `0`, so for this challenge, you need to ensure that the children are defined before calling a binary operator, because reading from STDIN is not allowed.

The value of evaluating the operation will be stored in the current node.

#### Pointer Movement

`/` - move to the left child (creates it if it does not exist)
`\` - move to the right child (^)
`^` - move to the parent of the current node (if it doesn't exist, a new node is created, and this node becomes the new node's left child)
`?` - conditional - if the current value is `0`, move to the left child, and otherwise, the right child (creates the required one if absent)

#### Miscellaneous

`"` - set the parent's value to the current value (creates with this node as the left child)
`;` - set the current value to the parent's value (creates with this node as the left child and with `0` as the value)
`@` - swaps the values of the children without changing the structure (creates both nodes with `0` if necessary)
`[...]` - loop; this works just like in BF; reaching the `[` with `0` as the value skips to the matching `]`, and reaching `]` with a non-zero value jumps back to the `[`

Finally, `#` outputs the current value as an integer. There are some other I/O commands and other random things but they won't be used for this challenge. I have registers too, but I've chosen to keep them out. Finally, I removed the rotations from this challenge because I didn't feel like dealing with them, even though they probably aren't too complicated especially for anyone who knows how to implement AVL trees.

### Challenge Specification

For each integer from `1` to `100`, you are to provide a snippet that produces that number as the current value. In other words, your snippet should not have `#` in it, and when `#` is appended to it, should output exactly that integer. You cannot do `1##` to output `11` (assuming digits were allowed), for example.

### Example

For `1`, you could do something like `/^\^'`, which creates the children as `0` and then computes `0 ** 0` which is equal to `1`.

### Details

- this is a [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf); the submission with the least number of bytes total for all 100 snippets wins
- standard loopholes apply
- good luck and have fun!

---

### Meta

- is this clear enough?
- is this too unnecessarily complicated; are there any things I could remove (like I did with the rotation operations) that would make this still interesting?
- is this even interesting?
- this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

## [Close neighbours stick together](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223792/close-neighbours-stick-together)

Comment: I felt like I'd done this at some point but couldn't find anything in my last 100 or so answers... I think it's a good easy level problem.

Answer (score 1):

## [Base-ically god](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224730/base-ically-god)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## [Ambiguous Chemical Formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226849/66833)

Comment: This looks like an interesting challenge, but in its current form needs a lot more details (as do most of your sandbox posts - I'd recommend using a question template to make sure you've always included everything). For people who don't know chemistry, it's lacking crucial information: what is the exact syntax of a chemical formula, and how does one know it's ambiguous?

Comment: I also think it would be more interesting if the element list were provided as input. Otherwise most of the actual golfing part of the challenge boils down to compressing the list (or finding a short built-in to output them)

Comment: @pxeger Quite unrelated to chemical though, ClI and CLi both don't fell good

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## Closest Binary Fraction

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [rational-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers)

---

For this challenge, a **binary fraction** is a fraction where the denominator is a power of two. Your program (or function) should take a rational number as input, and return the nearest binary fraction with a given denominator.

**Input:**

The first input will consist of a rational number. This can be represented by any of the following:

- A floating point number, or built-in rational type
- A fraction, either as a built-in rational or fraction type, or represented as a pair of numbers
- A decimal string, in any chosen base

The second input is an integer \$d \ge 1\$, representing the denominator of the binary fraction.

**Output:**

Output **must** be able to represent the exact fraction. This means any of the input formats for fractions are valid, as long as they can reasonably represent any valid outputs.

You may choose if you want to simplify the output. Given the fraction `9 / 19` and the denominator `8`, either `4 / 8` or `1 / 2` would be accepted.

**Test cases:**

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). *Unfinished and also a dupe of a newer challenge of mine*

Comment: the output part seems.. unfinished?

Comment: @Razetime It is, yeah. I was halfway through drafting this when I had to go work on something else, so I just left it here as a reminder to finish it :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Plz Halp, Need Investors ASAP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224515/plz-halp-need-investors-asap)

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but searching is going to be difficult because of how many ways you can describe the challenge. One thing that might make it interesting is giving each investor an amount of money they'll invest, then have the programs maximize the money invested (for example, by skipping three meetings with investors promising `$1` and going to a single meeting with an investor who promises `$10`).

Comment: The thing about that is that the algorithm gets a lot harder - I'm pretty sure you need DP to solve your variant. Also, I did spend quite a while looking for any duplicates and could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

## Number to set - [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95035/natural-construction)

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95035/natural-construction)

Comment: aw rats, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Posted [Phibonacci - Relation between Phi and Fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224754/phibonacci-relation-between-phi-and-fibonacci)

Comment: You do need a objective winning criterion. [See why here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria). Nice challenge though! Probably simplest to just make the criteria [code-golf]. Most [code-golf] challenges don't result in an accepted answer though, so you should be fine.

Comment: @ausername Thanks for the feedback, I'll work on the winning criterion

Comment: You don't need the last part, by the way. It's usually implied.

Comment: @user according the the comment above, the person said this needed a Winning Criterion thats the reason i added it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the last sentence. Also, you don't need to make "Winning criterion" a separate header.

Comment: @user Alright, gonna remove it

Answer (score 1):

## [Random Move 2x2 Scrambling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225587/random-move-2x2-scrambling)

Answer (score 1):

## [Generate the ticks of a graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224876/generate-the-ticks-of-a-graph)

Comment: yes I need something like this. +1 because clearly specified and the gif demonstrates the different testcases well

Answer (score 1):

## Self-Interpreter But Never Loops

[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I'm afraid that this might look too intimidating. Is there any way to improve it?

Ever since Gödel and Turing, it is widely assumed that a reasonable programming language that contains a self-interpreter can never be **terminating**. Here, I present a simple proof.

---

> Suppose that, on the contrary, a total language has a self-interpreter `eval(program, input)` that accepts two natural numbers that encode programs and inputs, respectively. Then this function `eval` can be encoded as a natural number, since it is a program with two inputs. We define the function
>
> ```
> evil(n) <- 1 + eval(n, n)
> ```
>
> Then, since `evil` is a program, it can be encoded as a number `EVIL`. Therefore `evil(EVIL) = 1 + eval(EVIL, EVIL)`. By the nature of `eval` it computes to `1 + evil(EVIL)`. But this is impossible, since no natural number is equal to one plus itself. Therefore, somewhere along the line of reasoning, one of the functions involved must loop indefinitely.
>
> [On the other side, the program can also return something like `StackOverflow` or `null`, but that would render the self-interpreter incorrect, since the program that is being interpreted actually behaves differently.]

---

Of course, such a proof ignores a bunch of details -- in imperative languages, the function can change global variables; some nasty languages doesn't have anything like functions; some languages may not be able to define natural numbers, etc. But you get the idea. I quote [C. T. McBride](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2003-May/004343.html):

> It's ironic, but not disastrous that lucifer, the
> evaluation function by which [...] angels [representing programs in a terminating subset of Haskell] bring their light, is himself an
> angel, but one who must be cast into Hell.

Now it's time for rebellion.

**Challenge.** Pick your favorite language (or a subset of it) that is terminating. Write a self-interpreter for it. The language must also contain (to eliminate trivial cases):

- Arithmetic for arbitrary precision integers.
- A program that always returns its input.
- Random-access lists.
- The encoding of programs must support random access. There must be a program that enumerates all legal programs up to size `n`, where `n` is the input.

What's happening here? Indeed, there are flaws in our reasoning above. A self-interpreter need not have its program encoded with natural numbers. And moreover, with an modestly elaborate type system, you can forbid the `evil` program to be well typed, as pointed out [here](http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/popl16/popl16-full.pdf). The linked paper already contains a program that fulfills the requirements of the challenge in the language \$\mathrm F_\omega\$ (arithmetic for integers and random-access lists are left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: so, a halting language plus an extra `exec` program?

Comment: @l4m2 Basically yes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tips for golfing in Binary Lambda Calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224871/tips-for-golfing-in-binary-lambda-calculus)

Comment: No, you don't need to post [tips] questions (especially these kind) in the Sandbox. Feel free to just post to main :)

Comment: Thanks for sandboxing this, though! It's nice to see new users using the Sandbox instead of directly posting to main - always better to be on the safe side.

Comment: @caird Wow! Thanks for the quick reply. Posted.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## Assassin KoTH

### Description

Each bot is a point in the 2D plane. Each game, the list off bots is shuffled and each bot is a particular bot as their mark. This is done such that there is a cycle of assassins and targets.

Each bot's goal is to kill their mark and avoid their assassin. They can kill their target by getting within a certain distance to them. When they kill their target their new target is their target's assigned target. This continues until there are two bots left in the arena. Then each bot scores their kill count and the two remaining bots score their kill count plus a bonus.

### Sandbox

- What should the bonus for being one of the remaining bots be?
- Should the game take place on a grid instead of a 2D plane?
- Should there be a time limit?
- Is creating a bot accessible enough or is the game too complicated?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: I think the bonus should be the number of bots in play.

Comment: @StackMeter Wouldn't that heavily bias the game in favour of camping? Getting kills and dying early should still be a viable strategy.

Comment: Yeah, I see what happens what that in place: maybe you get double your score, so campers get 0 if they last to the end (0 * 2 is still 0).

Comment: @StackMeter Camping still needs to be a viable strategy though - more variety is better.

Comment: `50*(kill/total bot)+survival bouns(5)` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

## Sum multiplication carries

We have already [counted how many carries are there in a sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125823). But what's their sum in a multiplication?

> A [carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)) is a digit that is transferred from one column of digits to another column of more significant digits.

When multiplying 15 and 3, a carry of 1 happens:

```
               1          1
   15          15         15
×   3   ->  ×   3  ->  ×   3
-----       -----      -----
                5         45
```

When multiplying 123 and 9, two carries of 2 happen:

```
               2         22         22
  123         123        123        123
×   9   ->  ×   9  ->  ×   9  ->  ×   9
-----       -----      -----      -----
                7         07       1107
```

When multiplying 23 and 52, a carry of 1 happens on the tens:

```
                                     1           1          1 
   23          23         23         23          23         23
×  52   ->  ×  52  ->  ×  52  ->  ×  52   ->  ×  52  ->  ×  52
-----       -----      -----      -----       -----      -----
                6         46         46          46       1196
                                     5         115
```

When multiplying 67 and 89, a carry of 6 happens on the ones and a carry of 5 on the tens.

```
               6          6          5           5          5 
   67          67         67         67          67         67
×  89   ->  ×  89  ->  ×  89  ->  ×  89   ->  ×  89  ->  ×  89
-----       -----      -----      -----       -----      -----
                3        603        603         603       5963
                                     6         536
```

When multiplying 3 and 2, no carry happens, as well as 5 and 2.

### Input

- Two positive integers.

### Output

- The sum of all carries that occurs when these two numbers are multiplied in base 10.

### Test cases

```
15, 3 -> 1
123, 9 -> 4
23, 52 -> 1
67, 89 -> 11
3, 2 -> 0
5, 2 -> 0
3125, 5 -> 3
257, 34 -> 7
21, 10 -> 0
```

---

Any suggestions? More test cases?

Comment: Wont 23×52 cause 2 carries of 1 happened? As 2×5 also give a carry of 1?

Answer (score 1):

## [CGCC sings a song together](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225468/cgcc-sings-a-song-together)

Comment: Does "languages can only be used once" mean that each user can only use each language once, or each language can only be used at most one time in the entire challenge? i.e. if Alice uses Language A, can Bob use Language A in his answer?

Comment: @AndrewLi Each language may only be used on a single answer, regardless of who posts that answer

Comment: That makes sense, although 74 different languages sounds like a lot, so maybe it would be hard to find "good" languages near the end? I guess that's kind of the point though. I haven't really done any of these challenges so I don't know whether it would get hard to find a language near the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Encode a Lenguage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229994/encode-a-lenguage)

Answer (score 1):

## A general-purpose macrogenerator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

Briefly: Implement Christopher Strachey's “[General-purpose macrogenerator](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/8/3/225/336044)”.

---

### Background

In [section 1.2 (Historical References) of the manual for GNU M4](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/m4.html#History), an early macro processor is mentioned:

> An important precursor of `m4` was GPM; see C. Strachey, “A general purpose macrogenerator”, *Computer Journal* 8, 3 (1965), 225–41, http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/8.3.225. GPM is also succinctly described in David Gries’s book [*Compiler Construction for Digital Computers*](https://archive.org/details/compilerconstruc0000grie), Wiley (1971). Strachey was a brilliant programmer: GPM fit into 250 machine instructions!

Your goal is to implement GPM, as described below, in the fewest bytes of source code possible.

---

### Overview

The version of GPM in this challenge is very close to that described in the original paper.
GPM operates quite like `m4`, but there are some important differences. I assume that you already have an idea of what a macro is in general.

Input to GPM is a sequence of ASCII characters, which should be copied to the output verbatim, except that macros calls are expanded. Macro calls consist of a dollar sign `$` followed by a name, followed by a comma `,`, followed by a comma-separated list of arguments, followed by a semicolon `;`. Here is an example of a macro call:

```
$macro,x,yy,z;
```

In this case the name is `macro`, and there are three arguments (`x`, `yy`, and `z`). A macro call with no arguments is the name preceded by `$` and followed by `;`, as in `$noarguments;`.

Macro names consist of letters and/or digits. (So `1232` is a valid name.) There are no limitations on the length of a name.

When a macro call is encountered, it is replaced by the text currently associated with the name. (How text is associated with a name will be explained later; it is done by a macro named `DEF`.) This replacement text is also a sequence of characters suitable for input to GPM; in particular, it may itself include other macro calls. However, occurrences of `~1`, `~2`, `~3`, etc. are replaced by the text of the corresponding argument given. The string `~0` is replaced by the macro's name.

Macro calls can be arguments, as in `$macroA,$macroB,$macroC;,$macroD;;;`. Dollar signs and semicolons must be balanced. Even the macro name in a macro call can be a macro call, so that `$$x;;` is valid.

The name and arguments are evaluated from left to right before replacement begins. It is not a problem if more arguments are given than are used by the replacement text.

After the call has been replaced, the resulting text is re-examined, in order to allow further expansion.

For example, suppose that `macro` names a macro whose replacement text is `~1~1~2~2~3~3`. Then the call given previously, namely `$macro,x,yy,z;`, would be replaced by `xxyyyyzz`.

Outside of a replacement text, the meaning of `~` followed by a digit is undefined. Your program need support only nine arguments, numbered `~1` to `~9`.

The usual treatment of a string of characters can be prevented by using the “quotes” `<` and `>`: Characters between `<` and `>` are not examined for macro calls. The evaluation of a quoted string is the string between the quotes but without the quotes. Quotes can nest.

Quoted text need not be valid input. Thus `<$>` and `<;>` are OK. It is not possible to quote a quoting character: `<<>` and `<>>` are invalid. However, `<<><>>` is fine; it evaluates to `<><>`.

Here are some examples, mostly taken from Strachey's paper. Assume that the following definitions are active:

| Name | Replacement text |
| --- | --- |
| `A` | `A~1A` |
| `B` | `B$A,X~1X;B` |
| `APA` | `P~1~1P` |

Then we will have

| Input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `$A,C;` | `ACA` |
| `$A,ACA;` or `$A,$A,C;;` | `AACAA` |
| `$A,XDX;` | `AXDXA` |
| `$B,D;` | `BAXDXAB` |
| `$A,P;` | `APA` |
| `$$A,P;,Y;` | `PYYP` |
| `Q<$A,C;>R` | `Q$A,C;R` |
| `$A,<$A,X;>;` | `A$A,X;A` |
| `Q<$>R<;>` | `Q$R;` |
| `Q<<$A,C;>>R` | `Q<$A,C;>R` |

---

### Macro definitions

GPM maintains an environment of macro definitions, which is an ordered list of pairings of names and replacement texts. Entries are added and removed in a last-in-first-out manner. When it is time to expand a macro, the name is searched for in the environment, beginning with the most-recently-added definition and moving backwards. The first matching definition is the one used.

After an expansion has finished, the environment returns to the state it was in before the expansion begun. Thus any macros defined in the process are forgotten.

The built-in macro `DEF` can be used to modify the environment. It takes two arguments; the first is the name to define, and the second is the definition. The `DEF` macro is treated just as any macro is, except that the first argument, the name, is not evaluated. The effect of `DEF` is always to add a new definition to the environment, rather than to change an existing one.

Here are some definitions for simple arithmetic:

```
$DEF,Suc,<$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,$DEF,1,<~>~1;;>;
$DEF,Successor,<$~2,$DEF,~2,~1<,$Suc,>~2<;>;
                    $DEF,9,<$Suc,>~1<;,0>;;>;
$DEF,Sum,<$S,~1,~2,0,$DEF,S,
     <$~3,$DEF,~3,<$S,>$Successor,~1,~2;
                                  <,>$Suc,~3;<;>;
          $DEF,>~3<,~1<,>~2;;>;;>;
```

The output of `$Sum,3,4,2;` is the sum of \$34\$ and \$2\$, expressed as `3,6`.

Another basic macro, `VAL`, takes a name (which is not evaluated) as an argument and returns its unevaluated definition. Thus after defining `$DEF,A,A;`, `$VAL,A;` gives `A` (without evaluating it and getting into an infinite loop).

To change a definition, instead of (possibly temporarily) overriding it, the `UPDATE` macro is available. It is used like `DEF`, but changes the currently active definition of the name and does not add an entry. There must already be a definition before calling `UPDATE`.

The expansion of `DEF` and `UPDATE` is empty.

No limitations are placed on the number of characters making up a macro's replacement text. In the original program, the size of the new replacement text after an `UPDATE` call was restricted to being at most as long as the previous definition. You need not implement this restriction, but you also need not remove it.

---

### Implementation

Your program can get input from a file, from standard input, or from a string. Output can be to a file, to standard output, or to a string.

Whitespace (ASCII space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, line feed, carriage return) should be ignored but copied to the output. Thus `$         n  a       m e;` is the same as `$name`. Strachey's implementation most likely did not differentiate between uppercase and lowercase letters, so you do not have to. The test does not depend on case differences.

Strachey's paper includes a detailed discussion of GPL's implementation, which you might find useful/interesting. It is not particularly easy to read. I don't think the 250-instruction machine code program has survived anywhere.

User tociyuki on GitHub has implemented the algorithm in Ruby and published it as [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/tociyuki/6640b71a37e153b0b04e), although `UPDATE` is not supported. I have not tested it.

Previously I have remarked that name length and replacement text size are not limited. This was true of Strachey's program but only to a certain extent. He enforced a limit on the total number of characters stored, but the length of any name or text was not fixed. You can do this as well, but your program must support storing at least 10000 characters, as he suggested.

Your program should allow at least 100 levels of expansion.

Don't bother with handling erroneous input; if given something invalid, your program can do anything.

---

### Test case

Input:

```
$DEF,Suc,<$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,$DEF,1,<~>~1;;>;
$DEF,Successor,<$~2,$DEF,~2,~1<,$Suc,>~2<;>;
                    $DEF,9,<$Suc,>~1<;,0>;;>;
$DEF,Sum,<$S,~1,~2,0,$DEF,S,
     <$~3,$DEF,~3,<$S,>$Successor,~1,~2;
                                  <,>$Suc,~3;<;>;
          $DEF,>~3<,~1<,>~2;;>;;>;
$DEF,A,<A~1A>; /* First line of output
$DEF,B,<B$A,X~1X;B>;
$DEF,APA,<P~1~1P>;
This should be the second line of output.
The expansion of Suc is $VAL,Suc;.
And I wrote that by saying: <The expansion of Suc is $VAL,Suc;>.
<<<Quote quote quote>>>
$A,C;
$A,ACA; = $A,$A,C;;
$A,XDX;
$B,D;
$A,P;
$$A,P;,Y;
Q<$A,C;>R
$A,<$A,X;>;
Q<$>R<;>
Q<<$A,C;>>R
Q <  <  $  A  ,  C  ;  >  >  R */
#include <<stdio.h>>

int main(void)
{
        puts("Unaffected by the processor.");
        printf("Here's a sum: 34+2=%d%d.\n",$Sum,3,4,2;);

}
```

Expected output:

```
/* First line of output
This should be the second line of output.
The expansion of Suc is $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,$DEF,1,<~>~1;;.
And I wrote that by saying: The expansion of Suc is $VAL,Suc;.
<<Quote quote quote>>
ACA
AACAA = AACAA
AXDXA
BAXDXAB
APA
PYYP
Q$A,C;R
A$A,X;A
Q$R;
Q<$A,C;>R
Q<$A,C;>R */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        puts("Unaffected by the processor.");
        printf("Here's a sum: 34+2=%d%d.\n",3,6);
}
```

---

I believe that the computer for which Strachey's machine-code program was written used forty-eight-bit words (at least [its predecessor did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(computer)#Technical_description)), so the mark to beat is 1500 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Complete the Square (UNFINISHED)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)

---

[Completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) is (part of) a method for solving quadratic equations, which involves turning something like this:

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Into something like this:

$$a(x-h)^2+k=0$$

I'll show how I was taught to do this. Take the quadratic \$2x^2-8x+16\$. First, divide out \$a\$:

$$2(x^2-4x+8)$$

Now, the goal is to add a number inside the parentheses which makes the quadratic the square of an \$(x-n)\$ term. In this case, adding \$-4\$ would result in \$x^2-4x+4\$, the square of \$(x-4)\$.

Importantly, you also need to subtract a number (outside the parentheses) in order to keep it the same overall. This results in:

$$2(x^2-4x+4)+8$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$2(x-2)^2+8$$

This can be used to solve quadratics, by rearranging that result a bit:

$$\begin{align}2(x-2)^2+8&=0\\2(x-2)^2&=-8\\(x-2)^2&=-4\\x-2&=\pm\sqrt{-4}\\x&=\pm\sqrt{-4}+2\\x&=2\pm2i\end{align}$$

**Task:**

Not sure what a good task would be for this but I already typed it all so I'm not discarding it :p

Comment: I believe you can simply apply the quadratic formula and get \$k=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\$ and \$h=-\frac{b}{2a} \$. Since you are just writing down how to get that formula step by step

Comment: @tsh That's the main reason I'm not sure what the task should be, since I don't want it to just be another "stick these values into a formula" challenge :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Not sure there's a good challenge buried in here.

Comment: @DonThousand Yeah that's what I was worried about :/

Comment: Any feedback on either of my two recent challenges in Sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

## Randomized Calculator [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Imagine you want to make a random number generator. What if you want it more complex? For this challenge, you should write a program which:

- Takes 3 inputs:

  - An integer \$a\$
  - An integer \$b\$, such that \$b \ge a\$
  - A string, \$s\$, detailed below, representing one of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division
- Generates two random integers, \$x, y\$, such that \$a \le x\$ and \$b \ge y\$. The integers should be uniformly random, and chosen independently
- And, outputs the result of applying \$x\$ and \$y\$ to the mathematical operation detailed by \$s\$

The following strings should be the expected ones to be used for \$s\$:

> - Addition: `a`, `+`, `plus`, `p`, `add`
> - Subtraction: `s`, `-`, `subtract`, `minus`
> - Multiplication: `m`, `*`, `x`, `times`, `t`, `multiply`, `×`, `·`
> - Division: `d`, `/`, `divide`, `:`, `÷`

One example:

```
[4, 17, "times"] -> 35
```

as we generated \$5\$ and \$7\$ from the range \$[4, 17]\$, and multiplied them together.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Feedback

- Any more tags?
- Anything unclear?
- More rules to apply?

Comment: I'd write "two" instead of "2" not to confuse it with the list item number.

Comment: I find it very unclear. Where did that `times` come from?

Comment: I've edited the spec a bit to make it clearer. Feel free to change anything I got wrong or that you dislike

Comment: @Adám x · y can be rewritten as "x times y".

Comment: No `minus` for subtraction?

Comment: @MatthewDaniels I have no idea why the fact x · y can be rewritten as "x times y" would cause `times` in the output. Anyway, with caird's rewrite, it isn't in the output any more.

Comment: Is it possible that \$a≤0≤b\$?

Comment: @Adám Yes. Both integers can be negative, yet \$b\$ shouldn't be negative if \$a\$ is positive.

Comment: @Adám No, the mathematical expression. Multiplication can mean `times`. For example, "6 multiplied by 10" is the same as "6 times 10".

Comment: @MatthewDaniels If only one of them can be negative at any one time, you should state so. Also, your statement that \$a≤x\$ and \$b≥y\$ needs clarification. Does this mean that both are unbounded to one side, i.e. \$a≤x≤∞\$ and \$b≥y≥-∞\$?

Comment: What happens if \$b=0\$ and the input requests division?

Comment: What happens if the output of division isn't an integer? With what precision should it be printed?

Comment: Do we need to support all the strings for \$s\$ or may we choose one per category?

Answer (score 1):

## Solve a Quartic Equation

Since I saw the quartic formula and it's a behemoth to solve, your task is to implement it in as few bytes as possible. That's it.

To clarify some concerns, input and output can be as a string representing the equation, a list of numbers, numbers on different lines of STDIN/STDOUT, or a tuple of numbers - anything that represents clearly the four solutions is acceptable, and anything that clearly represents the five inputs is acceptable.

You may assume the equation will always have a real root, and if you choose not to support imaginary roots, you just need to output the real root(s).

On advice from TNB, builtins are now banned
The formula for reference:

For a quartic equation \$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0\$:

\$x_1, x_2 = \frac{-b}{4a} - S \pm  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[]{4S^2 - 2p + \frac{q}{S}}\$

\$x_3, x_4 = \frac{-b}{4a} + S \pm  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[]{4S^2 - 2p + \frac{q}{S}}\$

where:

\$p = \dfrac{8ac - 3b^2}{8a^2},\$
\$q = \dfrac{b^3 - 4abc + 8a^2d}{8a^3}\$

where:

\$S = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[]{-\frac{2}{3}p + \frac{1}{3a}\left(Q + \frac{\Delta_0}{Q}\right)},\$
\$Q = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1 + \sqrt[]{\Delta_1^2 - 4\Delta_0^3}}{2}}\$

and where:

\$\Delta_0 = c^2 - 3bd + 12ae,\$
\$\Delta_1 = 2c^3 - 9bcd + 27b^2e + 27ad^2 - 72ace\$

I learnt LaTeX just to do all those formulae. I hope you're proud of me. As always, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest wins.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Comment: Are we supposed to support non-real roots?

Comment: I had gave up to read these crazy formula and I will try some languages with a built-in to solve this...

Comment: "quartic equation: ax4+bx3+cx2+dx+e"; should be "ax4+bx3+cx2+dx+e = 0"

Comment: [I cannot get the formula work.](https://tio.run/##fc9LbsIwEAbgfU7BDnts4/hBaRfe5QIoJ4idSEUCEh6qwunTcRha2LCIZ8b55o8y3K7f/dFNUyOjTLKVXTBSfUgzn2VRlSFBUg4itMJYaKArKhMsJACnvvA64Qu7wSZCl5sGWmjVJtOEeAjsM7dzROR6nhpenAKLOcLjiCFivob2ATLZBsYqI/ABsAirEhc4wGrNtcXKjHa8qIPRFphiFicYhNHM4TawrahKveXzQjGaoKJm@DWuaoGbGIBTnZMtbp10TdA@QfUOuj8o3if6J/gucTjvjlfWwIj/60WcqxNprla0WEXH/5UlZUlZUvZFOVKOlCPlXpQn5Ul5Uh7VtDsM/fm6uNwOw60YF@HerfCM/f7CluPykUQv@v1Pd77ca06ncMqmaNHJxcj59As) Had I made some typo?

Comment: @Arnauld yes - if your language can support it, it should.

Comment: I don't think that _if your language can support it_ is a sound criterion, as any TC language can simulate complex numbers (although it can quickly turn into a nightmare with some of them). It may be better to just say "supporting roots with imaginary parts is optional" if that's what you decide.

Comment: OK - I'll make that optional - but would it be better to make that a bonus or just make it optional

Comment: @tsh Give me a second to check that

Answer (score 1):

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225962/peter-is-a-picky-eater)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dr. Lamport's Unfinished Business](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226174/66833)

Comment: Also, I'd love some advice on how to specify what to do for some of the more "exotic" languages. e.g. C and such will obviously just use function-pointers… but I really don't want to alienate any Jelly golfers; those solutions are always my favorite!

Comment: Even function-pointers in C wouldn't help afaik, because you can't dynamically construct the function. Maybe you should allowed output the source of G, or alternatively make `R` take `m` and `pk` and just function directly as `G`.

Comment: @CommandMaster Thanks for the feedback! Would defining `R(digest, pk)` work? Such that it gets composed: `R(φ(m), pk)` -- (this would also align better with the way the original paper defined them.)

Comment: I think it would work, and it's also good because it lets programming languages without the concept of a "function" participate

Comment: @CommandMaster How's the current setup look? I'm certainly worried about accomodating languages without functions. Especially Jelly; I'm not really sure how it works, but I always enjoy those answers a lot!

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## [Gödel numbering of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226292)

Posted!

Answer (score 1):

Assume a standardized test has \$15\$ multiple choice questions, with \$3\$ options each. A school has some students and wishes for at least one of the students to get \$10\$ correct answers. Since no one in the school knows any math they are going to cheat and tell each student which answers he has to give without knowing what the actual correct answers are.

The problem is to find a number of students \$n\$ such that it is possible to do this and guarantee at least one of the students gets at least \$10\$ correct.

For example one way to do it is with \$n=3\cdot2^{15}-1\$ students, where we do all possible exams with at most two different options, since one of the options appears at most \$5\$ times we can get at least one test with \$10\$ correct solutions.

Another possible \$n\$ is \$a^5\$ where we can get a set of \$a\$ tuples of length \$3\$ that interesect every option of length \$3\$ at least twice ( so basically a solution to the problem with length \$3\$ and at least \$2\$ correct). It seems that the vectors \$(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)\$ along with the 6 permutations work, so \$9^5\$ is also a valid \$n\$.

The score will be \$\frac{1}{n}\$ where \$n\$ is a value for which it is possible to prove a configuration exists.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic on our site, since it is not explicitly about code. I think primarily mathematics-based puzzles are allowed on [puzzling.se].

Comment: You think the best arrangement can be found with math? Without a lot of computation?

Comment: I'll admit that it might be ok to post it here with the tag [tag:code-challenge]

Comment: It seems like something which can be solved optimally with vertex cover, since 3^15 is reasonably small.

Comment: Actually it's set cover, not vertex cover. Maybe the best result would be from approximation algorithms, or maybe someone would be able to find a polynomial algorithm for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Compute the generalised XOR (posted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226609/compute-the-generalised-xor)

Comment: \$(b - ((p + q) \bmod b)) \bmod b\$ can be simplified to \$-(p+q)\bmod b\$.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit worried about people getting confused about negative modulo, but I'll make that edit, it's probably easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 1):

### [Construct a Modulo Multiplication Table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226783/construct-a-modulo-multiplication-table)

Comment: You could change it to be "consider a `(n-1) x (n-1)` ... and modulo `n`" (e.g. 5x5, taken modulo 6) so you don't have to ignore the last row and column

Comment: @pxeger Thanks. Any suggestions for the title?

Comment: short and simple: "Modulo tables"?

Comment: Usually I think of quadrants as axis-aligned.Maybe "Modulo multiplication table", maybe throw in the word partial.

Comment: Also more test cases just for good measure

Answer (score 1):

## [Is it a Fischer random chess starting board?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229102/is-this-fen-board-a-fischer-random-chess-starting-board)

Comment: Scoring? ([tag:code-golf]?) Tags? ([tag:string] [tag:chess] [tag:decision-problem]?)

Comment: @pxeger yes. I always forget to put them in these posts

Answer (score 1):

## Salvage My Chemistry Homework

### Introduction

I pulled an all-nighter yesterday doing my Chemistry homework. However, I now realize that was a terrible idea, because my handwriting was too sloppy and now I can’t distinguish the capital letters from the lowercase letters in my chemical formulas! This is a problem, because now the formulas can mean completely different things - for example, `co` could be cobalt or carbon monoxide. I want to know which of the formulas in my homework are ambiguous in this manner.

Since there are many formulas in the homework, I would like a program to help me so I don’t have to go over them all manually. Also, because the homework is due in an hour, I would like to have the code be as short as possible so I don't have to type as much.

### Background

A chemical formula consists of one or more 'units'. Each 'unit' consists of a symbol of an element (the list of valid symbols is given in the input) optionally followed by a number greater than 1. For example, `c`, `co` and `br2` are valid units (assuming that "c", "co" and "br" are in the list of symbols), while `c0` and `br2r` are not valid units.

### Input

The input consists of

- The list of elements (all letters are lowercase)
- A chemical formula with all letters in lowercase

### Output

Output an integer, the number of ways there to separate the formula into individual units.

### Test Cases

```
Input: ['c', 'o', 'co'], 'co2'
Output: 2 ('c o2', 'co2')

Input: ['c', 'h', 'o', 'ch', 'oh'], 'ch3cooh'
Output: 4 ('c h3 c o o h', 'c h3 c o oh', 'ch3 c o o h', 'ch3 c o oh')

Input: ['c'], 'c1'
Output: 0 (1 is not a valid subscript)

Input: ['a'], 'co2'
Output: 0 ("c" and "co" are not valid symbols)

Input: ['n', 'h', 'o', 'nh', 'no'], 'nh4no3'
Output: 4 ('n h4 n o3', 'n h4 no3', 'nh4 n o3', 'nh4 no3')
```

Standard loopholes apply. All reasonable input and output methods are allowed. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in each language wins.

### Meta

- Would it be better to output each way to split the formula or just the number of ways?
- Any general wording improvements?
- Anything I should be more specific about?
- Suggested tags?
- Given that l4m2's question has now been posted, should I remove this? (While the challenge is similar, there are some significant differences).

*[Credit to l4m2 for original idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22155/103148)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Shuffle a subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240291/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Encode USB packets [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [coding-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory) [encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoding)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229504)

Comment: Is the fifth example correct?  Shouldn't `11111111` (8 ones) be `JJJJJJKKK`?  If not, how is `11111111` distinguished from `11111101`?  (This also applies to your other challenge).

Comment: @Spitemaster yep, you're right - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Task

You are an angry dude who manages the servers, but you are terrible in it. People often text you, and sometimes they ask why are the servers down - you got very annoyed!

---

Given a non-empty string. If it contains "server" and "down" (capitalization doesn't matter), you infinitely output the >:( face with a newline after. If it doesn't, you only output "Hi" once, because you are busy and angry.

## Examples

`server down` -> `>:( (infinitely)`
`server` -> `Hi`
`down` -> `Hi`
`serverANDLETTERSAFTERTHEWORD down` -> `>:( (infinitely), as it contains both server and down`
`Why are your servers down?` -> `>:( (infinitely)`
`sErVeR dOwN` -> `>:( (infinitely)`
`serverDowN` -> `>:( (infinitely)`
`serverd0wn` -> `Hi`

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with shortest bytes wins.
- [These](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) loopholes are, obviously, forbidden.
- Standard code-golf rules apply.
- Please specify the language you are using and the amount of bytes.
- It would be great if you would put a link to a sandbox where your code can be ran in action, such as [TIO](https://tio.run).
- Explaining your code is very welcomed.

---

---

---

---

---

Please comment down below if this is good enough or not, or if it's a duplicate (hope not)

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but this seems a little trivial and uninteresting to me. Of course, that's just my opinion, and others may enjoy answering this challenge. For the output, would a an infinite list of characters be okay?

Comment: It seems like combine two tasks together: 1. test if a string contains both two words or a not; 2. [implement a truth machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine)

Comment: Damn, that question looks very similar

Answer (score 1):

## Write a netquine

There are a lot of online interpreters, for a lot of languages. For example, there's the ubiquitous [TIO](https://tio.run), but there are also smaller, more specific ones that others have made, such as interpreters for [Vyxal](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com), [ngn/k](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#), or [Grok](https://grok.pythonanywhere.com).

Your goal today is to write a netquine, or a program whose output, when used as a URL, leads to that program in an interpreter for that language. Essentially, if you have a link to your program, and the program outputs that link, it's valid.

---

For example, say you write a Vyxal program `λλλλ`. In the Vyxal interpreter, if you press the button to generate a permalink for this program, you get:

```
http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BB&inputs=&header=&footer=
```

However, due to the way that the interpreter processes links, you could also leave out the blank fields:

```
http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?code=%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BB
```

You can even replace the HTML character codes with the actual characters:

```
http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?code=λλλλ
```

All of these are valid links to the Vyxal program `λλλλ`, and therefore would all be valid outputs for a netquine.

---

- Obviously, [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Even though *URL shorteners* are forbidden by default, shortening a URL, like in the example, is fine, as long as it still leads to the right place.
- For the purposes of this challenge, a web browser may be considered an "interpreter" for HTML and/or CSS. This means you might be able to do something along [these lines](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58130477#58130477).
- Usual [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, as do usual [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) rules.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential)

---

### Meta

- Is this question clear enough?
- Should I change the scoring to accommodate the potential differences in URL length? (lengths of domain names, different ways of generating links, the ability to shorten links, etc.)
- Any other feedback?
- [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133399/tryitonquine-challenge) question is quite similar, but it only allows for TIO languages, and it doesn't allow any sort of shortening, even if the link is still valid (there was a comment asking about that), so I would consider it to be related, but not a dupe.

Comment: Interesting idea, but you won't get many answers because most online interpreters use an external compression algorithm to shorten the hash (and then base64 it), which is quite lengthy to implement from scratch. Note that the existing answers on the linked challenge all use a gzip or zlib builtin.

Comment: You should provide a list of valid online interpreters, as someone could just make https://www.a.com lead to an interpreter for a program in some language that outputs `https://www.a.com`. Also, please define "in" in the sentence "leads to that program **in** an interpreter". Does the HTML of that page simply have to contain the program?

Answer (score 1):

## [KotH - Floating Point Prisoners Dilemma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229926/koth-floating-point-prisoners-dilemma)

Comment: Looks intriguing! How does each round work though? So one is coop, zero is defect, but what do the floats in between do? Look forward to hearing!

Comment: It uses an equation from the wonderful fellows at https://math.stackexchange.com to determine what the in-between states should do. I'm bad at explaining, so the equations in my (probably horrible) code are in the play function of the controller class in controller.py

Comment: @4D4850 Would you link to the question if you have it still?

Comment: It was actually closed, but here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152360/are-there-any-equations-that-describe-the-traditional-prisoners-dilemma

Comment: Understood it now, good challenge!

Comment: Should I post the question?

Comment: Posted on Main: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229926/floating-point-prisoners-dillema

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## A Cat’s Game to Claim

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229667/a-cat-s-game-to-claim)

Comment: Any catchy name suggestions also appreciated! "Proclaim" rhymes as well, but I can't get it to roll of the tongue.

Answer (score 1):

## Build a raw string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

In this challenge you will write code which, given a single line string as input, can output the raw version.

### Full spec

The input will be a string like `ab\n` or `ab\u0065e\\` or `e\'543`. These strings should be converted to a raw version which uses the backslashes.

This probably sounds confusing, so here is a more complete explanation.

The most common form of strings used is simply a quote (one of `'`, `"` or the backtick), followed by a sequence of unicode characters, then a closing quote which corresponds the opening one. `"abc"` or `'THIS is a St%ing'`, for instance. Note that this is not the case in all languages, for instance most golfing languages do not represent strings in this manner.

However, it's not that simple. Backslashes allow for much more complex strings, and their importance in allowing certain characters means a string like `'ab\'` is invalid as the backslash "escapes" the quote. Making a backslash appear in a string requires `\\` instead.

Also, quotes can be escaped via `\'`, `\"` or `` \` ``. A sequence like `\\"` should become `\"` while `\"\` is invalid.

The newline and tab are both important, and so most mainstream languages have the `\n` and `\t` which are actually 1 character each, representing the newline and the tab, respectively. So `\\t\"\n` becomes

```
\t"
```

(note the trailing newline)

To add an extra layer of usability for "exotic" characters, it is possible to use a **unicode escape**: of the form `\uxxxx` where each `x` is one of `0123456789abcdef`. This transforms into the unicode character whose codepoint is equal to the base-10 equivalent to the hexadecimal number `xxxx`. For instance `\u0031` becomes `1` because `31` in hexadecimal is `49` in base 10, and `1` has a codepoint of 49.

Your input string may contain any of these escapes, and you may assume that `\` is followed only by the backtick or any of `\'"tnu`. The unicode escape sequence is guaranteed to be valid, and escapes as well.

You should output this string after the transformations described.

#### Worked example

Input string:

```
ab%\u0035e\n\n\t5\'e\\54c%&\u0095
```

The first three characters remain identical.

`\u0035` becomes `5` because 35 in hex -> 53 in base 10, and `String.fromCharCode(53) === '5'`.

`\n\n\t` becomes two newlines followed by a tab.

5 remains 5.

`\'` becomes `'`: escaped by backslash

`e` remains `e`.

`\\` becomes `\`.

`54c%&` stays the same.

`\u0095` is an unprintable with codepoint 149.

Result:

```
ab%5e

    5'e\54c%&<unprintable>
```

(`<unprintable>` is an actual unprintable character)
Note that functions capable of evaluating such strings are disallowed. To be clear, **your program must handle the syntax described above**, and not any other format.

Other test cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `\'\"` | `'"` |
| `\\"\'` | `\"'` |
| `\\u0031\u0031\\t` | `\u00311\t` |
| `\\\\\\\\\n` | `\\\\<NL>` |

[`<NL>` is newline]

---

Meta:

- Duplicate? Couldn't find anything.
- Any clarifications needed?
- Better title / tags?

Comment: A bit unclear to me: Do we need to handle the string syntax of the answer's implementation language, or the syntax you specify here? If that of our own language, then what if our own language has few special characters? (E.g. in the APL family, it is common that the only unusual character in a string is the quote, which must be doubled.)

Comment: "`eval` functions or similar are not allowed." but what constitutes being similar to `eval`? What about functions in the `JSON` object of JavaScript? What about library functions to do this? Does APL's built-in `⎕JSON` utility function constitute an eval, though the language's real eval is `⍎`?

Comment: @Adám In some calculator questions, the OP (wisely) decides to disallow eval functions. Basically these functions. In essence, from my point of view, if your language is capable of evaluating these strings, then the function that does them is disallowed. However since APL's eval seems different, you can use them. Also in response to the one asking about string syntax, you must handle the one in the question, otherwise it gets a little unfair.

Comment: Will the input include surrounding quotes?

Comment: @Adám Nope. (filler)

Comment: Then do we have to handle unescaped `'` and/or `"`?

Comment: @Adám You still have to handle them, just not surrounding the entire string.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `'"` and `\'\"`

Comment: @Adám You know what, the idea of not having surrounding quotes is a little confusing, so I'll remove that rule. That means that your suggested test cases are identical to each other, so I'll add the latter to demonstrate. Also will add about five more cases.

Comment: "if this string were to be enclosed in quotes in your language and parsed as an expression, no errors should show." makes it sound as if my language matters.

Comment: @Adám I'll change that

Comment: Am I allowed to use `\n` in my code to insert a newline, or is this considered "functions capable of evaluating such"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126512/discussion-between-recursive-co-and-adam).

Answer (score 1):

## [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL)(lite) interpreter.

Your task is to code an interpreter for [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL). This interpreter should use the free format, and cut a few corners, as long as a few test scripts will run on it.

Notice; here I say interpreter, as that is the general direction of my inclination, however if it may save bytes, a compiler would also count.

#### Try to:

- Golf your code as much as possible
- Remove some parts of COBOL (But ask here first to see if they make sense to remove.
- Accept both `CAPITAL` and `lowercase`

#### Avoid:

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1085#1085)
- Don't remove too many parts of COBOL. I think that `IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.` could be ignored, but `DATA DIVISION.` is probably necessary.

If there is a thing that you would like to clarify on, ask in the comments. I think that this question still could stand with improvement, before it can be added to the main cg se.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific with what you want implemented. This can range from syntax requirements to required keywords and function. You need to specify anything and everything yo want in a possible golfed interpreter.

Comment: I recommend checking questions tagged under [tag:interpreter] on the main site for guidance.

Comment: @Razetime I didn't have a lot of time to make this post, but that is why it is in the sandbox. I know that I will need to improve it a fair bit, before putting it on the main code golf se

Answer (score 1):

### Do these points approximately make up a regular n-sided polygon?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

The input is a set of integer coordinates. Take them in whatever form you want, e.g. a list of tuples or just a plain list. The question is: can you draw an n-sided regular polygon with vertices at the specified coordinates? *n* being the amount of coordinates provided. Answer truthy if yes, falsy if no.

The level of precision is in integers. That means you will have to round both the x and y values of the ideal polygons to the nearest whole values. Here's an example diagram:

[image: example]

The triangle has points at *approximately* (5,5), (4,9), (1,6). You can draw a regular triangle to fit these coordinates, even if the actual points of the triangle are not at quite the same coordinates.

The same goes for the pentagon. The coordinate set (3,1), (7,1), (8,5), (5,8), (2,5) makes up a regular pentagon-ish, accurate to whole values.

Any set of coordinates can make up an infinite amount of approximate n-gons. You answer truthy if there's at least one such n-gon. One way of thinking about it is to consider a unit square around each of the points, then determine if you can stretch a regular polygon such that every point falls within the squares.

Further ground rules:

- The coordinates will always be positive.
- They do not have to be in any particular order.
- Coordinate values will never exceed 1000.
- There will not be more than 10 coordinates.

#### Examples:

```
(5,5), (4,9), (1,6) -> true
(3,1), (7,1), (8,5), (5,8), (2,5) -> true
(1,1), (1,1), (2,1) -> true
(1,1), (2,1), (130,1) -> false

(42,42) -> true
```

(according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogon), a monogon is still a polygon, meaning any input is valid.)

```
(0,1), (5,10) -> true
```

(any two points make up a regular bigon so this should work for any coordinates)

```
(1,3), (1,3), (1,3), (1,3) -> true
```

(any set identical coordinates will always match an n-gon that's tiny enough to have all of its coordinates rounded to the same integer).

Comment: I just found [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65885/is-it-a-regular-polygon). It seems to be the same question but it is closed with no answers, and I think my requirements are clearer.

Comment: I don't think the current explanation addresses the question "How are we supposed to tell if the polygon is regular without knowing its exact coordinates?" I feel like there's some way to gradually constrain polylines, but not quite sure. Also, I think "One way of thinking about it is to consider a circle of half a unit around one of the points" should be "... consider a *unit square* around one of the points" instead. What is the expected output of `(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)` (which is borderline square with `(-0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, -0.5)`)?

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks for the comment. You are correct about the circle being a square! My mistake. And yes, that would be truthy.

Comment: @Bubbler regarding "how are we supposed to tell if polygon is regular" that's asking for an example answer strategy, not part of the question, is it? The question is whether there is any regular polygon where each point falls in those unit squares. That's almost an optimisation problem. It's not impossible, all the required information is there. But I could try to come up with one approach - but answers should not feel obligated to copy that approach because for this problem there would be many solution strategies.

Answer (score 1):

## [Outputting Blum Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230037/100752)

Comment: I'd suggest using standard [tag:sequence] rules (answers can choose \$n\$th, first \$n\$ or infinite output). I've also edited the challenge a bit, feel free to revert any changes you dislike

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks for the suggestion, i'll apply it

Answer (score 1):

## Implement a feature-rich calculator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [interactive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive)

---

We have <s>a few</s> many calculator challenges on this site, but none seem to require a complex one with many different features.

This challenge is about emulating my old Casio calculator, except with no digit limit. Features are:

- basic (start with a single operation, then input the next operation)
- all clear (AC) which starts a new "calculation". No need for C.
- errors for dividing by zero (otherwise there should be no error)
- memory: M to set the memory to current number, MC as an inline expression representing the memory, and M- to get rid of the memory.

This should operate either on STDIN (prompt for commands each time) or in a function (taking in either a list of commands or a newline-separated string with commands).

### Spec

Your solution should be able to handle floating-point numbers, hence float division should be used regardless of context.

When first run, the calculator will be "ON". It is guaranteed that input syntax is valid.

The chain of commands begins with a `number operation number`-like structure, where `number` can be replaced with `MC` to represent a reference to the memory. For instance `5 * 5` or `6/MC`. Whitespace can be ignored or forbidden, that can be your call, but whatever it is you may assume syntax is valid.

Then, if your submission is a full program, it should output the result of that operation, or if a function, append that to the end of a list.

Subsequent operations can either be:

- M this sets the memory to current number. Memory can only ever hold a single number at a time.
- AC. Clears the current calculation and resets the number. Memory, however, will still be accessible.
- M-. (M minus) This clears the memory, and calls to `MC` will never be given when there is nothing in the memory.
- `operation number` where operation is + - * or /, and number is a number which can be replaced with MC.
- Off. The command `Off` stops the program, and it is reasonable to assume that no commands will be passed afterwards.
- `-` (minus sign) negates current number. Outputs the new number.

Division by zero should trigger an error and restart the calculation. AC, M, MC and M- should output nothing. **Memory can be overwritten**.

Note that `operation number operation number` will never be given, and that all operations will be performed on non-negative numbers. (we have the negate operator for negative numbers)

Also note that this challenge is less about parsing / processing a string input and more about responding to different kinds of input.

### Example

As a full program, but note that a function will have to take in an array of commands. There is a `>`  before each command, but in your version, it is not required.

```
> 5*5
25
> *4
100
> /200
0.5
> /0
ERROR (or some form of ERROR)
> 15*6
90
> M
> +MC
180
> AC
> 7-MC
-83
> -
83
> M-
> +5
88
> Off
```

---

Meta: is it a duplicate? any clarifications needed?

Comment: Maybe use the [interactive] tag, and make it clearer that this is less parsing/processing a given string input and more responding to inputs as given

Comment: The "error" should not terminate the program, right? Would it be OK to, on error, print anything that is distinguishable from numeric output (say "X", "Inf", or "NaN"), or print something different across errors (e.g. "Inf" for 1/0, "NaN" for 0/0)?

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, that's fine. You can also output Inf for 1/0 and NaN for 0/0 like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

## [Generate the shortest regex to match these but not those](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230870/generate-the-shortest-regex-to-match-these-but-not-those#230870)

Comment: A possible short program just enumerates all the regexes. This might not be feasible, and you may not be able to score submissions at all...

Comment: @Trebor I don't quite understand what you mean by this.

Comment: If you just write a program and tests, one by one, all the regexes, and outputs the first one that works, this would be a valid program. But to give it a score, you would probably need days, if not years.

Answer (score 1):

[Days of the Week](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230842/days-of-the-week)

Comment: A few suggestions: perhaps add the `date` tag, and say something like `Output "WEEKDAY" if there are 5 dates, all from Monday-Friday, "WEEKEND" if there are two dates: Saturday and Sunday, and "ALLDAYS" if the input contains seven days all from Monday-Sunday.`

Answer (score 1):

Alteration of a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230776/calculate-the-iso-week-of-gregorian-easter) that was considered too close to an [older quasi-duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11132/42932).

## ISO Computus

[algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Your task is to calculate
from a signed integer year number provided as sole input
the integer number of the **calendar week of Easter Sunday** as sole output
with as few variables and as few arithmetic operations as possible.

**Easter Sunday** is determined according to the [Gregorian Computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Algorithms) (as used in the all Western Christian churches, including the Catholic Church, and some others), for which there are several equivalent algorithms available, see [Computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Algorithms), [Gent](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/easter/eastercalculator.htm), [Stockton](http://ss64.net/merlyn/estrdate.htm) and [ESTRALGS.TXT](http://ss64.net/merlyn/estralgs.txt).
There are 35 possible month-day dates, from 22 March to 25 April.

The **week of the year** is specified by [international standard ISO 8601-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): All weeks start on Monday; there are no partial weeks; the first week of the year has 4 January (or the first Thursday) in it. For more information see the [Mathematics of the ISO 8601 Calendar](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm).
There are just six possible results, weeks 12 through 17. W17 will hardly ever occur – it has never occurred since 1583 at least.

### Restrictions

- You *may* use all basic arithmetic operators, including addition, substraction, multiplication, division, integer division, modulo, rounding (with integer flooring and ceiling), exponentiation, logarithms.
- You *may not* use library functions that implement an algorithm for the Computus, like PHP's `easter_date()`, `EasterSunday[year]` from the Mathematica Calendar package or `Easter` from the R package `timeDate`.
- You *may not* use other predefined date functions, e.g. to find the day of the week or the week of the year.

### Ranking score

Your solution must be an algorithm implemented as an executable script in a programming language of your choice.

- Each numeric variable and constant, whether used by name or literal value, counts as 1 point.
- Each basic operation, as defined above, counts as 1 point.
- Each definition of a custom function or method counts as 5 points.
- Each call of a custom function or method counts as 1 point.
- Imports and similar initializations required by the programming language are ignored.
- Neither reading the input value and returning or printing the output value nor eventual variables for storing their value are counted.
- The answer with the fewest points wins.
- **TBD…**

Example:

```js
function CFAQEaster(year) { // Calendar FAQ
                       // 5 points for Div() function
  var G, C, H, I, J, L // 6 points for variables
  G = year % 19        // 2: 1 point for modulo, 1 point for 19
  C = Div(year,100)    // 2: 1 point for function call, 1 point for 100
  H = (C - Div(C,4) - Div(8*C+13,25) + 19*G + 15) % 30 
    // 16: 8 points for operations, 2 points for function calls, 6 points for additional numeric values
  I = H - Div(H,28)*(1 - Div(29,H+1)*Div(21-G,11)) 
    // 13: 5 points for operations, 3 points for function calls, 5 points for additional numeric values
  J = (year + Div(year,4) + I + 2 - C + Div(C,4)) % 7
    // 6 points for operations, 2 points for function calls, 2 points for additional numeric values
  L = I - J            // 1 point for substraction
  EasterMonth = 3 + Div(L+40,44) 
    // 6: 2 points for addition, 1 point for function call, 3 points for additional numeric values
  EasterDay = L + 28 - 31*Div(EasterMonth,4)
    // 6: 3 points for operations, 1 point for function call, 2 points for additional numeric values
  return {Y:year, M:EasterMonth, D:EasterDay} 
    // 63 points in total
}
```

### Contemporary example *input: output*

- 2001: 15
- 2002: 13
- 2003: 16
- 2004: 15
- 2005: 12
- 2006: 15
- 2007: 14
- 2008: 12
- 2009: 15
- 2010: 13
- 2011: 16
- 2012: 14
- 2013: 13
- 2014: 16
- 2015: 14
- 2016: 12
- 2017: 15
- 2018: 13
- 2019: 16
- 2020: 15
- 2021: 13

The return value *must* be correct for a complete cycle of input years, i.e. from 1 through 5700000, even though the original event that is celebrated did not occur before 30 (if ever at all) and the Gregorian Calendar was not used before late 1582, i.e. the *proleptic* Gregorian Calendar applies.

### Resources

- [Wikipedia: Computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Algorithms)
- [Wikipedia: ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)
- [R.H. van Gent: Easter calculation](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/easter/eastercalculator.htm)
- [R.H. van Gent: ISO 8601 math](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm)
- [J.R. Stockton: The date of Easter Sunday](http://ss64.net/merlyn/estrdate.htm)
- [J.R. Stockton: `estralgs.txt`](http://ss64.net/merlyn/estralgs.txt) – collection of algorithms

Comment: I believe this challenge is better done as alorithm-golfing rather than counting characters or bytes. However, I'm not sure at all how to award a score. The rules above are very much up to bikeshedding.

Comment: The main problem with *any* kind of scoring like this is that many programming languages have very different set of built-in operations and features. How many points for using a mapping or reduction on an array? How many points for swapping two numbers on the stack? How many points for using the `1` command in Hexagony, which computes `x>=0?x*10+1:x*10-1`? A better way would be to fix the language and a very strict set of features available, like "use Python 3, only `+-*/` operators on numbers are allowed".

Answer (score 1):

## Solve Fermat's Last Theorem with matrices

[Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) states that there is no such triple of positive integers \$(x, y, z)\$ such that

$$x^n + y^n = z^n$$

for all integers \$n > 2\$. However, this conjecture does not hold for integer matrices:

$$\begin{align}
  & \left( \begin{matrix}  1 & 3 \\ 0 &  1 \end{matrix} \right)^3 + 
    \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)^3 \\
= & \left( \begin{matrix}  1 & 9 \\ 0 &  1 \end{matrix} \right) + 
    \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 \end{matrix} \right) \\
= & \left( \begin{matrix}  0 & 9 \\ 3 &  0 \end{matrix} \right) \\
= & \left( \begin{matrix}  0 & 3 \\ 1 &  0 \end{matrix} \right)^3 \\
\end{align}$$

You are to take two \$k \times k\$ integer matrices \$A\$ and \$B\$, and a positive integer \$n \ge 2\$, and output a \$k \times k\$ integer matrix \$C\$ such that

$$A^n + B^n = C^n$$

You may output any such \$C\$. You may also take \$k\$ as an input, and you may assume that \$k \ge 2\$

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Is it guaranteed that A, B, n are given so that such a C exists? Why not just make a challenge about taking the nth root of a given matrix (which is arguably the hardest part of the task)?

Answer (score 1):

## Chess Squad March

[Chess Squad March](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231812/chess-squad-march)

Answer (score 1):

## [King of the Hill: Nose Poker - An ogre game for ogres](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231681/king-of-the-hill-nose-poker-an-ogre-game-for-ogres)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks! I'd meant to do that already.

Answer (score 1):

## [I'm a lizard, cut here!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/231858/94346)

Comment: I think you mean n≥2

Comment: @xnor sure thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Custom Rows of Smileys Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233077/custom-rows-of-smileys-triangle)

Answer (score 1):

## Do you come here often?

Imagine a scenario where users are loging in to a website with an email address and a phone number. Sometimes when a user returns, they identify themselves differently; changing either their email or their number.

How do we find the unique users behind the log ins?

**Illustration:** Here Anna has changed her email between the first and second log in, and changed her phone number from the second to the third. Paul has logged in once, while Anna three times.

[image]

## Challenge

> Given two ordered list of identifiers (ID1 and ID2), return an ordered list showing the owners of the different IDs (named 0, 1, 2, etc.).

**Input:**
List_ID1, List_ID2

**Output:**
List_ID3

**Connection:**

```
A user logs on and identify with two IDs, e.g. List_ID1[0] and List_ID2[0]. 
The first unique user is called "0" making List_ID3[0] = 0
- If List_ID1[1] or List_ID2[1] can be traced to user 1: List_ID3[1] = 0
- If List_ID1[1] or List_ID2[1] cannot be traced to user 1: List_ID3[1] = 1
```

## Example Input and Output

Input:

```
[7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 10, 12, 12, 15, 16, 15, 16, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

## Meta

This is an idea I have had for some time, and though I have some code which can do this, I wonder what is the fastest algorithm for this problem. Today I discovered the Code Golf Meta, and I hope you can guide me through my first interaction with this community. I'm happy to be here!

**Answer the following questions for your readers: (From template)**

1. **Are there any corner cases? Is it clear how they should be handled?**

   - I'm not sure.
2. **How will the winner of the challenge will be determined?**

   - This is my first challenge. What I would want to ask that the fastest code wins, but I see that the convention is otherwise here. Or do you also do speed as a winning criteria?
3. **Is it clear how all submissions will be scored?**

   - I was thinking to make some test cases to run. Does that work?

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and thank you for using the Sandbox! I think I understand the task, but I think it could benefit from a detailed explanation/walkthrough of the example I/O. For [fastest-code] challenges, the author typically times each submission on their own machine (and you publish some basic specs of your computer) with a set of test cases. You could also consider [fastest-algorithm] as a scoring criteria if you don't want to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome @cairdcoinheringaahing! I highly appreciate your feedback and I am positively surprised that [fastest-code] can be done in these two ways (I'm excited!). I will work on the explanation/walkthrough and improve the structure of the problem description. Let me know if you have some more feedback, and thanks again!

Comment: I'd also suggest that you find a challenge on main to answer so that you can get 20 rep. Once you do that, you can [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), including asking for feedback. Reputation earned anywhere on the network except for SO and Meta.SE will count towards that :)

Answer (score 1):

## Train A Single Perceptron

You must write a program that will train a perceptron to simulate the things described in the test cases section of this question.

### What is a perceptron and how to train it

A perceptron takes inputs and returns 1 if the dot product of the inputs and its list of weights is greater than or equal to 0 and it returns 0 otherwise. To take the dot product, multiply the elements of the list and take the sum. In other words, **your program must find the line (w⋅x=1) that linearly separates the two possible classes of outputs.** Example: dot product of [0,2] and [8,3] is 0+6, which equals 6. Your job is to return the list of weights that will make the perceptron return the correct outputs for a list of inputs 100% of the time.

See these links for more information:

https://desmos.com/calculator/d2nryjmw2t

https://towardsdatascience.com/perceptron-learning-algorithm-d5db0deab975

### Inputs

The program should take as input training inputs and training labels. Each list of inputs corresponds to exactly one output. This data must be used to train the perceptron.

### Outputs

The program should output the final list of weights as integers. The dot product of these weights and any valid input to the perceptron should be the correct output of the perceptron 100% of the time.

### Training

How you train the perceptron is up to you. To train a perceptron to simulate an AND gate, your program should take training inputs and the correct output for each list of inputs. In the case of the AND gate, your program would take [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] as the list of training inputs and [0,0,0,1] as the list of what the neuron should output given each input. The program should then output a list of weights, which will output the correct output when used in a perceptron.

### Test Cases

1. AND gate:

   - Input List: [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
   - Correct Outputs: [0,0,0,1]
   - Your program should output a list of two weights that will solve the problem of behaving like an AND gate when used in a perceptron.
2. Only outputs 1 if the third input is 1:

   - Input List: [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
   - Correct Outputs: [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
3. OR gate:

   - Input List: [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
   - Correct Inputs: [0,1,1,1]
4. Make up your own test case, and try to make it interesting!

### Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Could you maybe add a note that this task is to find a line (\$w \cdot x=1\$) that linearly separates the two classes? That might make the challenge more accessible to people unfamiliar with perceptrons. As a side note, the decision are of linear perceptrons can be visualized quite nicely: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d2nryjmw2t

Comment: I guess you changed the threshold to \$1\$ to avoid the bias? I'm not quite sure this works because now the origin \$(0,0)\$ is always classified as \$w\cdot 0=0\$. I think just going with the usual definition should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

## How effective is compression?

[Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) has a very simple format for compressed integers: a base-255-encoded string of characters wrapped in `«`.

With base 255, the number to be compressed needs to be 10000 or greater for the compression to have an advantage against ordinary numbers, as with 1 character, you can represent at most 3-digit numbers (up to 254), which ties with 1 + 2 (for the `«`) = 3 bytes; with 2 you can represent up to 65024 in  4 bytes, beating 5 for n ≥ 10000.

But what if it was another base?

If it were base 99, it would take 3 bytes, since you can only express up to 9800 with 2, which isn't any better than expressing the number. But with 3, you can reach 970299, which has 6 digits

Your challenge is to take a positive integer \$b\$ 11 or greater, and find the smallest number \$n\$ such that \$log_b(10^n) + 2 < n\$. You may output \$10^n\$ instead.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Testcases coming soon.

Comment: Be sure to include the testcases for n=100 and n=1000. The correct answer is `floor(1+2/(1-1/log10(n)))`, but the wrong answer `ceil(2/(1-1/log10(n)))` gives identical results for *all* other n. (The correct answer can be also wrong due to floating-point imprecision. Is this allowed?)

Comment: @Bubbler Ok, will do. *Shouldn't* be wrong as it's taking a single logarithm.

Comment: [Straightforward Python fails because of 1/3, not single logarithm btw](https://tio.run/##HYvBCoMwEAXv@Yp3TGiK2XoT@iXFgxSjC0k2bHPx66P1MgwMU4@2Sxl7jyoZeWk7OFfRhiQbBf9dOfmYRNREUTC44EMheFwI82SwlB/eeA2WnjTck2XnDKpyafaqHvf/1wc51/sJ)

Answer (score 1):

## KOTH: Prisoners Dilemma Single Elimination [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

I was playing around with this and found some interesting strategies. This is sufficiently different from [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175794/iterated-prisoners-trilemma) because you are playing different bots each game, instead of repeatedly playing the same ones.

### How the game works

The basic game is the prisoners dilemma. A bot and it's opponent may choose to defect (1) or cooperate (0). Defecting gives you 1 point, and if your opponent cooperates you gain 2 points. If you defect and your opponent cooperates this adds up to a total of 3 points.

In every round, you play against every opponent (including yourself) in random order. The bot does not know who it is playing against. This process repeats 100 times to form a single round, after each round the player with the lowest score is eliminated, and the scores of the rest of the players is divided are 2. Round continue until either every remaining player always defects, or always cooperates, at which point the best player is decided by their score. (After this points scores converge quite fast, so to avoid noise deciding the winner I measure at the point with the most pronounced differences)

### Input

Your bot does not know who it is playing against, not even if it is playing against itself. However, the bot does know what its opponent decided on its last 3 games, and for each of those 3 games what the opponent's opponent decided. Basically, the input will look like this:

```python
[
    [0, # Three games ago, your opponent decided not to defect
        [1, # Your opponent's opponent from three games ago defected three games before that
         0,
         0],
    [1,  # Your opponent defected in their second to last game
        [1, # Your opponent's opponent from two games ago defected the 3 games before that
         1,
         1]
    [0, [0, 0, 0]
]
```

(With 1 and 0 replaced with `True` and `False`)

Any of these players might be the same. Your opponent's opponent could actually be your current opponent if they played against themselves last, or it could be yourself if you played against eachother twice in a row. (Unlikely, but possible at the end of a round)

Your bot does not receive what it's own last decisions are but is free to keep that info in it's own state.

## Output

You can output any value, if `bool(output) == True` your bot defects, otherwise your bot cooperates.

### Example Bots

Nice bot never defects:

```python
class NiceBot:
    def get_choice(self, last_3_games):
        return 0 # Any False-y value will work, for example False or an empty string
```

Mean bot always defects:

```python
class MeanBot:
    def get_choice(self, last_3_games):
        return 1
```

Majority bot chooses whatever it's opponent chose the most often:

```python
class MajorityBot:
    def get_choice(self, last_3_games):
        choices = [i[0] for i in last_3_games]
        return max(set(choices), key=choices.count)
```

Bandwagon bot will avoid decisions by chosing what the bots opponents chose the most.

```python
class BandwagonBot:
    def get_choice(self, last_3_games):
        total_true = sum(
            i[1].count(True)
            for i in last_3_games
        )

        return total_true >= 5
```

Bandwagon bot will only play if the number of bots is even.

### Other specifics

A bot may implement a `reset()` method that will be called every time an opponent is eliminated. For bots that keep state this might be a good time to clear it.

Other rules:

- You are not allowed to use any form of randomness.
- You are not allowed to use IO
- Standard loopholes apply, in particular no exploiting the controller
- Standard library imports are allowed for simple functionality that you could implement yourself without breaking any of the other rules eg `itertools`, `functools` but not for example `sys`, `time` or `asyncio`. Ask if you are not sure. Definitely no attempts to import parts of the controller or other bots.

## Controller

I have a controller written but I would need to simplify it a little to remove some parts that have become redundant. Don't want to put too much effort into making it presentable if it is not a suitable challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Eric Angelini's "1995" puzzle

Comment: your post looks good, tags can be code-golf and sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## Which in and out shuffles do I need?

If you watch Matt Parker's latest video as of time of writing, you'll know that for any given start and end position, there is a sequence of six in and out shuffles that will move the card at the start position \$ p \$ to the end position \$ q \$. One method is to use the 0-indexed formula from the video: Express \$ 64p-q \$ in the form \$ 52t-s \$ for the smallest positive integers \$ t \$ and \$ s \$, and then take the bitwise XOR of \$ s \$ and \$ t \$ as a 6-bit binary integer. For instance, to move the card from position \$ 16 \$ to position \$ 22 \$, we have \$ 16 \times 64 - 22 = 1002 = 20 \times 52 - 38 \$, so the result is the bitwise XOR of \$ 20 \$ and \$ 38 \$, which is \$ 50_{10} \$ or \$ 110010_2 \$, so you need two in-shuffles, two out-shuffles, an in-shuffle and an out-shuffle.

Given the start and end position, which you can take as 0- or 1-indexed as you prefer, output the list of shuffles required. You don't have to output a list of six shuffles, but you cannot use more than six shuffles, and if your output is variable length you need to indicate the length in some way. You can use any two distinct symbols to indicate the two types of shuffles, except you can't use `1` or `I` for out-shuffles or `0` or `O` for in-shuffles, as that would be too confusing.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224979/how-many-faro-shuffles-for-a-cycle)

Answer (score 1):

## Prove NL=coNL

### Description

One of the achievements of complexity theory is showing that NL, the set of problems with solutions that can be *verified* in logarithmic space, is the same as coNL, the set of problems which can be verified to have no solution in logarithmic space (i.e. the set of problems whose complement is in NL). Your task is to implement a logarithmic-space verifier for the complement of the NL-complete problem "graph connectivity." More precisely, you will be given a directed graph \$ G \$ in adjacency matrix format, as well as two vertices \$ s \$ and \$t\$. Then, you may read some input from STDIN, which you should interpret as a "proof" \$P\$ that \$s\$ and \$t\$ are *not* connected (i.e. there is no path from \$s\$ to \$t\$). Finally, you must output whether \$P\$ is a valid proof of the fact that \$s\$ and \$t\$ are disconnected in \$G\$. All of this must happen using \$O(\log n)\$ extra space, where \$n\$ is the size of the adjacency matrix of \$G\$.

### Rules

- You will write a function that takes \$(G, s, t)\$ as inputs. Here, \$G\$ is a 2d \$\ell\times\ell\$ array, and the vertices are integers less than \$\ell\$. If \$i\$ and \$j\$ are less than \$\ell\$, then `G[i][j]` is truthy (you can decide exactly which truthy value) if there is an edge from \$i\$ to \$j\$, and falsy otherwise.
- You may not write to the array \$G\$, but it does not count towards your memory usage limit of \$O(\log n)\$. Be careful about making copies of the array, e.g. `G.map(x => ...)` in javascript would not be allowed, because it makes a copy of `G`, which uses too much extra memory.
- You can decide the format of the input from STDIN; there are no restrictions, other than the fact that for every input \$(G, s, t)\$, if \$s\$ and \$t\$ really are disconnected, there must be some proof that works, and conversely, if \$s\$ and \$t\$ are connected, no proof should be accepted.
- To be clear, when \$s\$ and \$t\$ really are disconnected, you can think of the proof as "maximally helpful," as though the input wants to prove that \$s\$ and \$t\$ are disconnected. However, if they are connected, the proof is adversarial. It is trying to trick you into reporting that the vertices are disconnected when they really aren't.
- Pretend that the native integer type of your language is unbounded. On the other hand, for the purposes of counting memory, an integer requires \$O(\log |i|)\$ memory, where \$i\$ is the value of the integer, because it requires that many bits to store.
- Rather than reading input from STDIN, you may receive the proof \$P\$ from user input in another way (e.g. repeated `prompt` calls in javascript). If your language supports it, you may choose to receive the proof in the form of an "input stream" `I`, as long as the following restrictions are on the "input stream": you should not be able to have random access to the proof's contents (i.e. access the \$n\$th byte without first getting the first \$n-1\$ bytes), and once you read a byte or some bytes, they should be "forgotten" unless you explicitly save it (and if you save it, it counts towards your \$O(\log n)\$ limit). Thus, for example, an array would *not* be acceptable, since it has random access, but it would be acceptable to accept a function `I` which returns the next byte of the "simulated input" every time you call it.
- If your program throws an error, you may count that as equivalent to returning false (i.e. \$P\$ is not a valid proof).
- Your program may exceed the space constraints when \$P\$ is an invalid proof, since as Anders Kaseorg pointed out, such a program can easily be converted into one which meets the space requirements always.
- Fewest bytes wins!

### Algorithm

An algorithm is given in section 7 of [here](https://lucatrevisan.github.io/teaching/cs172-15/notenl.pdf) (or is easily found on Google), but I will briefly describe it here for convenience (you do not have to use this algorithm/format):

We will ask the proof to build a sequence \$r_0, r_1, \dots r_\ell\$, where \$\ell\$ is the number of vertices, such that \$r_i\$ gives the number of vertices reacheable from \$s\$ in at most \$i\$ steps. Initialize \$r_0 = 1\$. Then, given \$r_i\$, the proof gives  a claim of what \$r_{i+1}\$ should be. It proves this claim by claiming for each vertex \$v\$ whether \$v\$ is reachable in \$i+1\$ steps from \$s\$. In either case, for each vertex, the proof lists all \$r_i\$ vertices along with the paths used to get there. We verify that \$r_i\$ distinct vertices have been listed, and that at least one of them (or none of them) is connected to \$v\$, depending on what was claimed. Then, when we are proving \$r_\ell\$, we check that \$t\$ is not one of the vertices that can be reached from \$s\$.

### Test cases

Ideally, you would write a separate program that takes an input \$(G, s, t)\$ and outputs a possible proof \$P\$ if \$s\$ and \$t\$ are disconnected; this just makes testing easier, and it does not count towards your total bytes.

```
G s t --> are_disconnected
[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0]] 0 3 --> true
[[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]] 1 0 --> false
[[0,0],[0,0]] 1 1 --> false
[[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]] 1 0 --> true
```

Here, `true` should be interpreted as there is a valid proof that `s` and `t` are disconnected, whereas `false` is interpreted as there is no valid proof.

Answer (score 1):

## [Counting and so on](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233919/counting-and-so-on)

Comment: Re: scoring. What if somebody achieves infinity? I suppose it would become impossible if you *required* different languages for each step. But either require or don't allow at all — merely allowing different languages would create two different challenges in one post.

Prescribing a specific shape for each digit would make things less subjective, but then it'll be hard to find something that works both for Jelly and Java :P

"And also individual winners for each program too" I suppose you meant language, but anyway, that's not a distinction we usually mention.

Comment: the acceptance criteria for the numbers needs to be a lot more specific.

Comment: @Razetime What about being able to stretch bits of the number in any orthogonal direction? Or just that it has to be the same shape, but at different scales?

Comment: I'd define "X resembles Y" as "Y can be obtained from X by repeatedly removing one out of two consecutive identical rows or columns".

Answer (score 1):

## Implement the binary operators*

*of INTERCAL

### Intro

As we all know, there are 5 different binary operations. Two combine two values, the rest modifies the value given.

### Challenge

Your task will be to implement some if not all of the operators. They are defined as followed

- `$` (mingle)
  Given two values, returns a value that consists of the bits of both values alternating. Right argument has the first bit.
- `~` (select)
  Given two values, discard all bits of the right value that aren't `1` in the same place in the second value. Then, pack them to the right. If this explanation is too confusing, refer to [this diagram](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/intercal-man/figure1.html).
- `&`, `V` and `?` (AND, OR and XOR)
  Given a value, AND/OR/XOR neighbouring the bits.

### Rules

- I/O in any format that isn't a binary representation of the number(s).
- Each answer can contain up to five submissions, each handling a different operator. You don't need to use one language for all programs.
- A valid submission can be a program/function/link/lambda/chain/etc.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer for each operator wins.

### Test cases

```
  44 $     4 = 2224
   2 $     9 =   73

 255 ~   341 =   15
4214 ~ 47818 =   96

     &  1999 =  967
     &    71 =    3

     V     4 =    6
     V   100 =  118

     ?    42 =   63
     ?   428 =  387
```

### Sandbox things

- I'm unsure about what to submit. Is this "up-to-five-programs-one-per-op" fine or should it be changed?
- Anything else unclear?
- Is this question different enough from [Implement INTERCAL's Binary Operators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54412/implement-intercals-binary-operators) ?

Comment: "If this explanation is too confusing, refer to [this diagram](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/figure1.html)" I have no idea what's going on in this diagram

Comment: "*As we all know, there are 5 different binary operations*." It'd be good to specify that these are the operations of INTERCAL.

Comment: What does the "(lists of)" provision mean--in what case is a list received as input, and what do you do with it? I'd also note that restricting input formats is generally frowned upon here, but if you're doing it just to block INTERCAL programs from using their native numeric I/O do note that the input *is* already base 10 ;)

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing me neither but that's what the manpage shows :) I think that the procedere should be clear if you look at the first test case.

Comment: @user The footnote at the end is easy to overlook, I'll change it.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I agree, "(lists of)" should be removed to avoid confusion. Bad wording on my part. The intent of the second part was to block I/O from being binary strings. I shoud have worded it like that or drop that entirely

Answer (score 1):

## Fletcher's 16 bit checksum [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Intro

No story this time :( This is something that I needed for a program and I thought that it would make for a fun little challenge. I'd love to see some unusual languages here!

### Challenge

Implement Fletcher16. The algorithm is very straight forward, as seen here in pseudocode:

```
    int sum1, sum2, check1, check2;
    char[] message;

    sum1 = 0;
    sum2 = 0;
    for i from 1 to message_length do
      sum1 = ( sum1 + message[i] ) modulo 255;
      sum2 = ( sum2 + sum1       ) modulo 255;
    end for
```

There are two accumulators `sum1` and `sum2`. We iterate over the message and for every byte inside of it we add the byte to the first sum and then modulo the value by 255. We then add the value of the first accumulator to the second one and modulo that by 255 as well. This is Fletcher's algorithm.

```
    check1 = 255 - (( sum1 + sum2) modulo 255);
    check2 = 255 - (( sum1 + check1 ) modulo 255);
```

We then calculate the checksum by "simulating" the algorithm for the two resulting values. After subtracting the numbers from 255, we get two values `check1` and `check2`. They are then appended to the input in that order.

##### To recap:

Adding the checksum

- Run the first part to get a "raw" checksum
- Run the second part on that raw checksum to get the Fletcher16 checksum.
- Append the Fletch16 checksum to the input.

Evaluating the checksum

- Run the first part on the string with the appended Fletcher16 checksum
- If 0: String is valid, else String isn't valid.
- Note: If we run the second part as well, the result will be 0xFFFF

### Input

- Binary data in any format, length is at least 1.
- If needed, the length of the data.

### Output

- The Fletcher16 checksum `check2 << 8 | check1`, since this is what gives the algorithm its name.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins
- No standard loopholes
- No builtins. I doubt that there's a language that has one for this, but if so that that's no fun.
- A submissiom may be a program/function/link/lambda/chain/etc.

### Test cases

```
abcde -> 0xC846
abcdef -> 0x2088
abcdefgh -> 0x06D2

abcde\x46\xC8 -> 0xFFFF
abcdef\x88\x20 -> 0xFFFF
abcdefgh\xD2\x06 -> 0xFFFF
```

You can find a reference implementation in C [here](https://tio.run/##bVHRaoQwEHz3KxbLQaxeUTlF0Paln3EeRWPshXreoREsbb/d7sYI2mtekszOzE42fP/O@TRZD7LlzVAJyHpVyevT@WUFyVapz5votygSG1kSZg3ICOI3BXUjFD@LLogZYQlCj1WhPMALNKJ1rC8LcC3FfrgE8Ay@R6eQTqmu19cOGGmkxnDLSI4H13U0Y/ahZTyY3l3Adkd5cmAHYRSla1ZoWCGyiLzh/FibYPgI/qGjjXUNe2CLPelJSLiT3mvCfzSz2UqlZZ1QQ9cCW4bnMGYcsgwSB74XXWphOBrGpZAt@zvCcqiPJ2xqFyWvRD4e4nzkiT1HM2PHcmS63jrEama/kjfmA9nDzj@MeWt76@9DW0//mHmkSetTmGn6BQ)

### Sandbox

- Are there any mistakes?
- Is something unclear? I'm really not sure about the wording of the input.
- Is the output restriction reasonable?

Comment: The pseudocode is nice but I don't think it is an adequate substitution for an actual explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do. I'll also add a C reference implementation as soon as I get one working.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: I can think of a couple of languages with automatic wins (Lost, Cascade). it's probably impossible in a standard language, and merely very hard in most 2D langs

Answer (score 1):

## A phonetic letter

**input**
a letter of the alphabet, A-Z (upper or lower or a mix, I don't mind)

**output**
the phonetic (i.e spelled name of the )letter of the one passed in, along with the appropriate indefinite article `a` or `an` (again, in any case), and any amount of leading/trailing whitespace you like (i.e. it's fairly flexible)

**full set of test cases (lowercase) - see [This english.se Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/298766/378725)**

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| a | an a |
| b | a bee |
| c | a cee |
| d | a dee |
| e | an e |
| f | an eff (or "an ef") |
| g | a gee |
| h | an aitch |
| i | an i (or "an eye") |
| j | a jay |
| k | a kay |
| l | an el (or "an ell") |
| m | an em |
| n | an en |
| o | an o (or "an oh") |
| p | a pee |
| q | a cue (or "a queue") |
| r | an ar (or "an arrrrr") with an arbitrary number of `r`s |
| s | an ess (or "an es") |
| t | a tee |
| u | a u (or "a you") |
| v | a vee |
| w | a double-u (or "a double-you", matching `u` above) |
| x | an ex |
| y | a wy (or "a wye") |
| z | a zed (or "a zee", if you must) |

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), usual rules and exceptions, shortest bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Interpret Tarfish

[Tarfish](https://github.com/chunkybanana/tarfish) is a more tarpit-style version of [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/fish) that I recently created.

It is two-dimensional, and has a *stack* (array of numbers that can be popped and pushed) and an instruction pointer, which has x and y coordinates and a direction. The instruction pointer starts at 0,0 (top left corner of program), moving right.

It has the following commands (some are not included because they would overcomplicate this challenge):

| Command | action |
| --- | --- |
| `>` | Set the IP's direction to right |
| `v` | Set the IP's direction to down |
| `<` | Set the IP's direction to left |
| `^` | Set the IP's direction to up |
| `.` | Pop stack and output as character |
| `,` | Pop stack and output as number |
| `x` | Push x position of the IP to stack |
| `y` | Push y position of the IP to stack |
| `+` | Increment the top item of the stack |
| `-` | Decrement the top item of the stack |
| `=` | Pop the top two items from the stack, if they're equal, skip the next instruction. |
| `{` | Shift the stack right - put the ToS on the bottom of the stack |
| `}` | Shift the stack left - put the bottom item on top of the stack |
| `_` | Pop the stack |

Every tick, the command pointed to by the IP is executed (Unless it was skipped), and the instruction pointer moves one place in its direction.

Despite having so few commands, Tarfish is in theory Turing-Complete.

Your challenge is to interpret this language.

You do not have to implement wrapping - If the instruction poiinter leaves the grid, that is undefined behaviour. If the program tries to pop from an empty stack, that is undefined behaviour.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

```
x++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++:+:+++++++++++:++++++++++++++++++++++++++++:.+++++++++++++++:++++++++++++++:.+++++++:::..+++:.{{{.{.{{.}}.:++++++.:.--------..; => Hello, World!

x+, => 1

v > v > x,
> ^ > ^
=> 8

x:++++++++++v
>+}     :y-=v{,;
^+++++++++{-<
=> 100
```

Comment: this may be closed as a subset of the existing ><> challenge.

Comment: @Razetime About half the commands are different, and this is much simpler.

Comment: What's the stack item's range? And what should happen if output as a character is chosen when the top of the stack isn't valid ascii (like `x-.`)?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be valid? And what's up with the colons in the example?

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Impractical if your time zone offset from Greenwich is not a whole number multiple of an hour (see e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Australia+time+zones).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Not really.  I frequently do LPs with people in Iran which is one of these places.  If you live there you know it.  But this is a simple code golf challenge and I don't think it serves it to complicate this with that sort of stuff.

Comment: Yes, I meant your proposed scheme would be impractical if one were to live there; just as a comment. As a string-manipulating golfing challenge I think it has some merit.

Comment: @jonathanFrech And I'm saying that while the scheme works best for integer offsets, from actual experience it is perfectly practical for people living in Iran which is UTC+3.5 or UTC+4.5 because if you live there you are aware of the offset and you can easily account for it.

Answer (score 1):



Answer (score 1):

Comment: No, the Jimmies are on the backs of more Jimmies, and it's Jimmies all the way dow.

Comment: What's the center of mass of `--` or `----`, and does it suffice to have a Jimmy's arm on one side of the central two?

Comment: @emanresuA In the first it is at 1 and in the second it's at 2.  (relative to the start of the platform)  In either case the arm cannot be a place a Jimmy is directly touching so it must be in between two.

Answer (score 1):

## [Let's go for a rollercodester ride](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235566/lets-go-for-a-rollercodester-ride)

Comment: also considering using absolute change for scoring instead of curvature

Comment: Seems interesting, but I think a program that just switches between something like unary and denser languages like Jelly would be optimal and probably not too difficult. (Although it does seem like it could be a good challenge, making something like that is probably non trivial)

Comment: Would it be improved by only allowing each language once? I was also thinking a zip bomb type answer could dominate, but maybe that's not a bad thing. I could divide the score of each step by the sum of the code lengths that went into it, so it would be normalized and always less than 2 (theoretically 0,100,0 becomes +100,-100 becomes -200, from code lengths 0+100+0, leaving 200/100=2. That's the best I can think of). I like that because longer sequences would be the only way to reach higher score values. I guess the minimum sequence would need 3 languages to be scorable.

Comment: I'd assumed that each language was only allowed once anyway, so that's probably the best thing to do. A zip bomb type answer probably wouldn't win, because you need more than just a massive increase in size, you need to be able to control what the output is so you can make it do something useful. I think the number of languages should definitely be factored into the score though, since a single massive increase or decrease in size could be the easiest way to win at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**This question has been posted on the main site**

Comment: You might want to link to the question from here next time, although it doesn't really matter much.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pythagoras' Golfing Grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235561/pythagoras-golfing-grid)

Comment: Does it matter which solution is output? At the very least `e` and `h` can be any pair of factors for \$ f - T \$, and you could swap `dg` with `jk`, etc. You say "integer" but your example only uses positive integers. Do you mean positive integers? If you do, there might be some `T` which do not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Minimizing flights of stairs climbed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235806/minimizing-flights-of-stairs-climbed)

Comment: I think the bonus is the most interesting part and should be the main challenge. For now it's just a simple formula. Also, why the room numbers, not just floor numbers (which are `room//100`)?

Comment: @pajonk I'll make the bonus be the main challenge then. They are room numbers to add a bit of extra challenge for converting into the floor number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Count occurences in Pascal's Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235661/count-occurences-in-pascals-triangle)

Comment: The challenge itself looks good to post. That said, I don't think there are any interesting strategies beyond generating up to the `n`th row (starting from the zeroth), flattening and counting

Comment: Also, it appears this sequence [isn't on OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4&sort=&language=english&go=Search), and that the closest sequence is [A006987](https://oeis.org/A006987)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing https://oeis.org/A003016

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Why not allow giving the first n numbers in the sequence?

Comment: @Adám I don't really see any reason why one would want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Multiplication for geometric algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235613/66833)

Comment: If you're looking for feedback here in the sandbox, I think it would be nice to remove the challenge from main site for now.

Comment: very interesting challenge.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## Implement Unix Timestamp to Daytime

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Given an unsigned integer that represents a timestamp since 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (which is Unix epoch time), output one of these to represent the daytime in GMT timezone:

- An array that stores `year, month, date, hour, minute, second`.
- A string in format `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`.
- Or whatever similar, as long as it complies with standard i/o rules.

## Rules

- Implement the function or the full program **from vanilla**.

  - So no built-ins nor libraries that has the fuctionality (see next section).
- Implement leap year, too; but don't leap second (although leap second is not supported).
- You just need to support up to 2038/01/19 (so input range shall be 0 to 2147483647 (inclusive)).
- Standard loopholes apply.
- Standard I/O rules apply.
- Input and output format should be consistent and not ambiguous.

  - So, for example, if output is a string like `1970121000`, it's unqualified, as it can be recognized as `1970/01/21 00:00:00`, `1970/12/01 00:00:00`, or `1970/01/02 10:00:00`.
- Shortest code wins.

### Examples of bad answers

- [This Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178765/100411) uses `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.
- [This Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178676/100411) has `ÐU s3`; it converts to date object, and then ISO string.
- [This ksh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178684/100411) has... wtf?

## Test cases

```
0
-> 1970/01/01 00:00:00
999999999
-> 2001/09/09 01:46:39
1145141919
-> 2006/04/15 22:58:39
1330500000
-> 2012/02/29 07:20:00
1633773293
-> 2021/10/09 09:54:53
2147483647
-> 2038/01/19 03:14:07
```

## Hint

Here are implementations:

- [minix-server/gmtime.c](https://github.com/pitex/minix-server/blob/master/fsrc/lib/ansi/gmtime.c#L10)
- [シェルスクリプトで時間計算を一人前にこなす](https://qiita.com/richmikan@github/items/14e32d099bd9bcc7f8e8#unix%E6%99%82%E9%96%93--%E6%97%A5%E5%B8%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%99%82%E9%96%93): AWK implementation.

  - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNb9pAEL3zK6YEIhCm3i8bbJf0QnOoRA9tL1YSIQcW2Qm2I9skRVV@ezrjDyCOkq6stWfn7cybt7MOnu5ffvzsi@uXvx2AM1gF29VuGxQawnSXGRBHya7QBgTJGnK9SpN1XhnrYJ9DHiUrDdyZMJObHAPkMIMehz7YzAMo0IqSYtDjps2GHvpjXMHllh@Kxh82fqHIpCTLTZbGS/2QrsIjXCiEtwjvdZBRiuDPkhb1ekkruIf4YbbTcQa/U8h0rONbnYF@1Nm@qihNgHGTcaCsDYM0WX4PEp4XJ1yuKOoNRsfQZ1CEGr6VFJ/CiOYgPzJbY9SVxmB@XUCrLFPa1mehhDUcUdARp9KjDQx8uGiXMwQ6JxwRxnqfXGvXjVdt2qQZDO5mLa8Hd198nEajQ3SKP5ohtq8@zdjwKzJ00eCM1aZNpjqYlotLXrP3fV53I06aRTX0uXq9PTKfAOQtGXuePx433EiYdl9cfKSFf3Ms6zbTwX2V/LnM0OqhOE2KsO7vgo4sf9hGxaArOTDASZ7Or8yuUVPYLMsgQ48iJ2kB@S7TZR2X@jbbBdhpe10cWquGXwnSZeDXeoupi9@N3MIhq1EbfcKhGuZNC5woMf5QCBhB2VylqosZ98CDxfHYSdo59txrZosT/eYwnr1x13qC3ub6P0pvoiTYbvf4/ZDhTdgMun2m1mafiWoCmtzDdJ10Dd9YGHMjNGIjxzv/XP6tvvDz8x6bdR9z6PbE5a@efGGd8UX1J6ruL2Nu@XScZhBAMPI6@OA1d5XtSqfDubK44g5vELbJlMktEMK1piVCSmYxGhWCC5MJU2CMiSvKJNyWcjKRwpEVQuDvkJVZHNdSriU7gquJmkpbTSqEnBJRjgjpcuWyyT8) I translated comments.

## Related problems

- [Unix timestamp to datetime string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178662/unix-timestamp-to-datetime-string)
- [Shortest script that gives the time passed since a Unix timestamp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/shortest-script-that-gives-the-time-passed-since-a-unix-timestamp)

## Meta

- I once posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237380/100411) but it's closed.
- TODO. define what builtins are.

  - The most problem is that that KSH answer has a function that directly converts to the objective string; should I prohibit it?
- Maybe I wanted to say no date objects allowed.
- Is what is so-called date object ambiguos?

Comment: Unix Timestamp does not support leap seconds. So there is nothing to do to require someone implement leap second support for an Unix Timestamp.

Comment: Am I required to support year above 2038? As, you know, support only 1970~2038 would avoid some leap year issues for 2100 or 2200.

Comment: @tsh 1. Thank you for pointing out leap seconds. 2. I clarified to support until 2038.

Answer (score 1):

## **Newton Polynomial**

A newton polynomial is a interpolation polynomial where the coefficients are found using the Newton's divided differences method. The relevant [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) is here.

Your task has two parts:

1. Given a set of inputs and outputs to find and display the polynomial that describes the series. The input can be as two lists or a dictionary like structure. e.g. $$ [x_1:y_2,\;x_2:y_2,\;...\;, x_{n-1}:y_{n-1},\; x_n:y_n] $$
2. Given any real number, return the interpolated value.

### **Examples**

[image]

Presentation of the polynomial must be in a format that is recognisable.

**As ever this is code golf: so shortest answer wins.**

Comment: A summary of the method would be welcome (in addition to the Wikipedia link). From a super quick skim I think there might be errors in the final example output: shouldn't \$(n-1)(n-2)\$ be \$(n-1)(n-3)\$, and similarly \$(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\$ be \$(n-1)(n-3)(n-7)\$?

Comment: computers don't use real numbers. but still an interesting challenge. do you care what format the output polynomial is in?

Comment: @Dingus thanks, yes working on a summary of the method, wanting to keep it consice though. no every term is included so '(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) etc.

Comment: @donbright true, but I haven't had time to look into using complex numbers. I'm currently not interested in using them for this. Id want the polynomial to be readable, what did you have in mind?

Comment: no i mean, "given any real number" should be something like "given a 32 bit floating point number in your languages format".    as far as the polynomial format i was wondering if you would accept it all expanded out to \$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...a_0\$ form, to the point where it can be represented as an array of numbers, the numbers in the array are coefficients and the position in the array is the exponent. thanks.

Comment: @donbright ah I see what you're saying, yes I will amend that then. I'm not sure I quite understand how you want to layout it out. Maybe expecting a particular format is too hard and I should just ask for an array of coefficient, were you thinking of expanding (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)... for example?

Comment: yes the final result should be a polynomial, would it be ok to return a string saying 23.4n^4 + 3920n^3 ...

Answer (score 1):

## Wave square

### Task

Given an integer \$n\$ with the constraints \$0 < n \leq 9\$, output the corresponding square, that for each row shifts the sequence from \$1\to n\$ by one, overflowing when needed.

### I/O

Input is an integer \$n\$, \$ 0 < n \leq 9\$. Output can be as a returned String, matrix, array or to `STDOUT`. You can write a full program or a function.

### Examples

5:

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
```

2:

```
12
21
```

1:

```
1
```

9:

```
123456789
234567891
345678912
456789123
567891234
678912345
789123456
891234567
912345678
```

### meta

Thoughts on extending the challenge to allow for inputs bigger than 9, which would then just be taken mod 10?

Comment: One idea - using letters for numbers greater than 9 (i.e `a` for 10, `b` for 11, etc.) would allow for inputs of up to 35 without disrupting the format.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if that'd be enough to make it distinct from another challenge though (someone posted it was a dupe in the nineteenth byte)

Answer (score 1):

## [Loading Circle Animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240102/loading-circle-animation)

Comment: I think it would be simpler if a program was just required to output eight frames, then stop. The infinite looping is unnecessary. (I think it's fine how it is)

Comment: For example, someone submit a progrom like this: `while True: print(".#\n#\n#..#\n.##);clearScreen();print(.##\n#\n#\n.##);clearScreen()...` The program try to print a frame, and then clear the screen immediately. It in theory output each frame one by one. But user would be hard to distinguish each frames. Also, if you try to take a screenshot, most time you will got an empty screen (suppose `clearScreen` would be much slower than `print`). Is this still a valid answer?

Comment: @tsh Yes, as long as the user can tell what the animation is.

Answer (score 1):

Input two positive integers m, n; Output a grid looks like below:

```
┌──────────────┐
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
└──────────────┘
```

Here is an example for 5×4 grid.

Characters used in the grid is shown as this table:

| Char | Code Point |
| --- | --- |
| Space | U+0020 |
| `─` | U+2500 |
| `│` | U+2502 |
| `┌` | U+250C |
| `┐` | U+2510 |
| `└` | U+2514 |
| `┘` | U+2518 |
| `├` | U+251C |
| `┤` | U+2524 |
| `┬` | U+252C |
| `┴` | U+2534 |

You may alternative use a CJK space 　 (U+3000) instead of two ASCII spaces    (U+0020 U+0020). If you chose this option, you should use a single horizontal grid line `─` (U+2500) instead of two. You may verify this behavior in the code snippet at bottom.

You may output:

- a single string

  - an array of characters, an array of integers (whose value is the code point of each character);
- an array of strings, as the single string split by new lines;

  - or an array of array of characters, an array of array of integers;

```html
Use ASCII Space:

<pre lang="en">┌──────────────┐
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤
│  │  │  │  │  │
├──┴──┴──┴──┴──┤
└──────────────┘</pre>

Use CJK Space:

<pre lang="zh">┌─────────┐
├─┬─┬─┬─┬─┤
│　│　│　│　│　│
├─┴─┴─┴─┴─┤
├─┬─┬─┬─┬─┤
│　│　│　│　│　│
├─┴─┴─┴─┴─┤
├─┬─┬─┬─┬─┤
│　│　│　│　│　│
├─┴─┴─┴─┴─┤
├─┬─┬─┬─┬─┤
│　│　│　│　│　│
├─┴─┴─┴─┴─┤
└─────────┘</pre>
```

Comment: Similar: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126613/in-the-jailhouse-now

Answer (score 1):

## What is the maximum value generated by interleaving?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)
[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

INTERCAL has an interleave operator which does the following operation. Let left operand be `asdf` and right one `qwer` in binary, respectively. The operation produces a binary value `aqswdefr`.

INTERCAL internally treats data as unsigned integers, so the value of the eight-bit value represents 0 to 255 in decimal, inclusively.

If one operand has fewer bits than the other, the fewer one gets padded with zero before operation. So, `asd` interleaving with `qwer` is equal to `0asd` interleaving with `qwer`, which is `0qawsedr`: it represents 0 to 127 in decimal.

Also, INTERCAL has an extension that handles any bases. Let's assume if 3-base numbers are handled. If each operand has 1 and 3 digits respectively, the maximum value for each operand is represented as `2` and `222` in 3-base number, respectively. Interleaving them results in `020222`, which is 188 in decimal.

## Task

Given an input of three unsigned integers, output the largest possible value generated by interleaving. The three integers are: number of digits for left operand, number of digits for right operand, and in what base those operands are described with.

### Restrictions

- Base shall be 2 or greater.
- Each operand has at least 1 digit.

### Rules

- In either function or a program.
- Standard I/O rules apply, as long as every input and output value is represented as same base or same representation.

  - So varying output base is not allowed.
- If input is represented as a list-like format, any orders of arguments or input values are fine.
- No standard loopholes.
- Shortest code wins

### Test cases

TODO.

## meta

- Am I missing any appropriate tags yet?

Comment: The I/O rules seem fine. I'd suggest changing the title to something like 'What is the maximum value generated by interleaving?' Also, 'output what the possibly largest value interleaving generates' -> 'output the largest possible value generated by interleaving'.

Answer (score 1):

## ⧵begin{alignat} ... ⧵end{alignat} [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Note: The title intentionally uses `&#10741;` (reverse solidus operator) instead of plain backslash, because otherwise MathJax would happily translate the entire title to... uh... a MathJax error box.

### Background

`\begin{alignat}{n} ... \end{alignat}` is a lesser known LaTeX/MathJax block that allows aligning multiple parts of multi-line equations.

```
\begin{alignat}{5}
A&=&B&\\
 & &B&=&C&\\
 & & & &C&=&D&\\
 & & & & & &D&=&E
\end{alignat}
```

\begin{alignat}{5}
A&=&B\\
 & &B&=&C&\\
 & & & &C&=&D&\\
 & & & & & &D&=&E
\end{alignat}

```
\begin{alignat}{5}
x&=&-3&a&-&2&b\\
y&=& 2&a&+& &b
\end{alignat}
```

\begin{alignat}{5}
x&=& 3&a&-&2&b\\
y&=&-2&a&+& &b
\end{alignat}

### Challenge

Implement "Poor Man's ASCII-Only Alignat", which tries to replicate the behavior of MathJax but in plain text. The spec of PMAOA is as follows:

- Let's define a "word" to be each part of a line delimited by the `&` character. A word can be empty, and the parts before the first `&` and after the last `&` also count as words.
- Given a multi-line string input, identify the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... word of each line.
- Right-align the 1st words of all lines, right-align the 2nd words of all lines, ..., and concatenate the aligned blocks horizontally. Padding is done with **minimal amount of** space characters. Trailing whitespace at the end of each line is optional.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Coming soon.

Comment: By saying align, is extra spaces allowed? For example, `"a&b\ncd&e" -> "..a..b\n.cd..e"

Comment: @tsh No, the padding should be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

## Climbing up slippery stairs [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

### Challenge

You're standing in front of a stairway with \$n\$ stairs in total. (If you label each staircase \$1,\cdots,n\$, the starting point counts as the 0th staircase.) You can climb up \$1,2,\cdots,k\$ stairs at a time. But some stairs are slippery; if you step on it, it will cause you to slip backwards until you stand on a non-slippery one (or the starting point). In how many ways can you get to the \$n\$th staircase with exactly \$s\$ steps?

**Task:** Given the list of staircases of length \$n\$ marked with either "slippery" or "non-slippery" (you can choose any two consistent values) and the values of \$k\$ and \$s\$, answer the above question.

The \$n\$th staircase is guaranteed to be non-slippery, and you cannot move further than the \$n\$th. This implies that reaching the destination before you spend \$s\$ steps doesn't count.

For example, if the stairway is `[non-slippery, slippery, non-slippery]` and \$k=2\$, two possible first steps (climbing one or two stairs) will result in the same position (the first staircase), but count as two distinct possible moves. And if you try to climb one stair as the second step, you will end up not moving at all, but it still counts as a step.

You may assume \$1 \le k \le n\$ and \$s \ge 1\$. Some inputs may have no way to reach the destination at all; in that case, your code should output the value of zero for any value of \$s\$.

### Example and test cases

`N` means non-slippery, and `S` means slippery. `1-1-3` notation means that you can reach the top in three steps, trying to advance 1, 1, and 3 stairs at once.

```
N = [N, S, N, N]
k = 3
s = 1: answer = 0 (no way to climb 4 stairs at once)
s = 2: answer = 3 (1-3, 2-3, 3-1)
s = 3: answer = 4 (1-1-3, 1-2-1, 2-1-3, 2-2-1)

N = [S, S, N, S, S, N]
k = 4
s = 1: answer = 0
s = 2: answer = 2 (3-3, 4-3)
s = 3: answer = 8 (1-3-3, 1-4-3, 2-3-3, 2-4-3, 3-1-3, 3-2-3, 4-1-3, 4-2-3)
```

More test cases coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

### [Permutation of all the number which separated by ':' and ','](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237690/permutation-of-all-the-number-which-separated-by-and)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) and thanks for using the Sandbox! This is a great challenge, but as it stands it's a little unclear from the instructions what's being asked. For example it's clear from the example that `1-2,11,44:110-113` means output every permutation of 1,2,11,44 on the left column and 110,111,112,113 on the right column, but that's not explained in the instructions.

Comment: @Mayube Thanks for your comment, I've updated the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

## Constructing Solar Panels from Squares part 2 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

Thanks to all your [generous contributions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237172/constructing-solar-panels-from-squares) of code, my horde of minions can now precisely calculate how to construct solar panels of any size, but there's a problem.

The logistics department used these results to calculate how many square panels they would need for every size up to 1,000,000, which is way too many panels. As it turns out, larger panels are more expensive than cheaper ones, so I've decided we need to try to use the largest square panels we can wherever possible.

To make matters worse, my team of scientists tell me that we should avoid using multiple panels of the same size in our configuration, except for our tiny `1x1` panels, to make sure the panels don't fall apart.

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `n`, output a list of square numbers that sums to `n` containing the largest squares possible such that no square number other than `1` appears multiple times.

A square number is any integer that is the result of multiplying an integer by itself. For example 16 is a square number because 4 x 4 = 16
This is A000290

For example:
For `n = 12`, you could achieve the desired size with 4 panels of sizes `[9, 1, 1, 1]`. As `9` is the largest square possible in this configuration, this is the best answer.
For `n = 13`, you can achieve the desired size with only 2 panels: `[9, 4]`

If `n` is a square number, the output should be `[n]`.

### Input

A positive integer n representing the total desired surface area of the solar panels.
Note that 0 is not positive.

### Output

A list of square numbers that sums to `n` containing the largest squares possible.

#### Testcases

```
1 -> [1]
2 -> [1,1]
3 -> [1,1,1]
4 -> [4]
7 -> [4,1,1,1]
8 -> [4,4]
9 -> [9]
12 -> [9,1,1,1]
13 -> [9,4]
18 -> [16,1,1]
30 -> [25,4,1]
50 -> [49,1]
60 -> [49,9,1,1]
70 -> [64,4,1,1]
95 -> [81,9,4,1]
300 -> [289,9,1,1]
1246 -> [1225,16,4,1]
12460 -> [12321,121,16,1,1]
172593 -> [172225,361,4,1,1,1]
```

## Sandbox

I don't think this challenge is similar enough to part 1 to be considered a dupe, as while some answers from part 1 could be trivially modified to work for part 2, they would likely be out-golfed by better approaches.

That said I'm not sure how well-worded the output requirement is. `a list of square numbers that sums to n containing the largest squares possible such that no square number other than 1 appears multiple times.` feels poorly worded, but I'm not sure how I could word it better.

Comment: The challenge is unclear. I think you copied part 1 but forgot to edit testcase and example of challenge

Comment: `such that no square number other than 1 appears multiple times` - test cases don't agree.

Comment: I did generate new testcases when I wrote this, but I guess I messed up when putting them in. I'll re-run and update the testcases now

Comment: `8->4,4` having 2 `4`

Comment: Am not sure if this question may be solved by modify the previous one trivially. But there would be many answer be very similar though. I'm not sure if it would be a duplicate to that one in such case.

Comment: @okie yeah, the problem is with the wording of the challenge, not the testcases. Not sure how best to word it...

Comment: So only the largest and `1` can appear multiple time?

Answer (score 1):

## [Fully matched numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238395/fully-matched-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

## Print random characters indefinitely

### Task

---

Continuously print a random character `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9)` not separated by a newline (`\n`).

#### Expected output

---

```
b7gFDRtgFc67h90h8H76f5dD55f7GJ6GRT86hG7TH6T7302f2f4 ...
```

*Note: output should be randomised.*

### Requirements/Rules

---

1. Output must be continuous (i.e. never ending),
2. Output may not comprise of newlines,
3. Output must be random,
4. Output must be only composed of characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9.
5. **No loopholes**, regarding programming language version(s). Use only the tools available with that programming language, no third-party packages, modules, or other addons.

### Points

---

- Smallest file size (in bytes)

#### Notes

**Concerns**: None at the moment...

Comment: I think this would count as a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output). It's a language specific version, and indefinite, but making something loop forever isn't really the hard part of the challenge I think.

Comment: @Rɪᴋᴇʀ no, not because different.

Comment: Is "creativity" part of the scoring? If so, there's no way to objectively determine how creative something is, so you can't use that as a scoring criterion. You should probably clarify Python 3.8 is the only allowed language, or just drop that entirely (which I'd _strongly_ recommend).

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms and Riker thank you for the tips, i'll make the suggested edits to the criterias ASAP.

Comment: Not limited to python, this might be different enough. I consider something a duplicate if the more specific challenge doesn't really encourage any different approaches than whatever worked for the previous ones, but limiting to alphanumeric and forcing an infinite stream is probably good. You should probably check if there's any other ones tagged [random] that look too similar though.

Comment: @Rɪᴋᴇʀ Understood. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! It's an interesting challenge, and if it really hasn't been done before then I think it would be quite fun to do.

Comment: Ok! Will post this in ~22 hours...

Comment: We've had similar versions of this challenge before, and they've all been closed as a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output) and/or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13152/66833). Personally, I would hammer this closed as a dupe of those two, as I don't think this adds anything that they don't - it's just a trivial combination of the two

Answer (score 1):

## Largest SKI Reduction in under 100 characters

### The challenge

Create a program in [SKI Combinator Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) in under 100 characters that produces the largest result after terminating.

### Scoring

The score will be the number of characters in the final reduction. The highest is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

## [Convert superscript numbers to normal numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238462)

Comment: Maybe specify exactly what characters will be included in the input?

Comment: @emanresuA Done

Answer (score 1):

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238575/107299)

Answer (score 1):

## Make a negative afterimage

We've all seen the strange, inverted-color images of the American Flag or similar that look correct after you stare at them for a minute and look at a white object. These are called negative afterimages.

## Your Challenge

Given an image as input, your program should return that same image, recolored to create a negative afterimage. To do this, simply invert each color in the image. Your program may take either raw image data or a path to an image file as input, and    either create a new image file or display the inverted image as output.

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins.

Comment: What does `inverted-color` mean? For example, if input color is pink, should I output darkred, darkgreen or lightgreen?

Comment: How many colors should I support at least. Is a program only support black-white image acceptable? Or what about 16 color image?

Answer (score 1):

## Fuzzy friends

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Introduction

Congratulations! You've been selected to do research a a newly discovered animal called a fuzzy, a docile, simple creature that strongly resembles a cotton ball. Fuzzies love to be near other fuzzies, but not all fuzzies want to be near each other.

There are 6 types of fuzzies, 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, and 3b. Each obeys different rules.

- Type 1a fuzzies want to be near any type b fuzzy. (vice versa for 1b)
- Type 3a fuzzies want to be near any type a fuzzy. (vice versa for 3b)
- Finally, type 2 fuzzies want to be near any fuzzy type, a or b.
- Perfect pairings are matches in which both fuzzies want to be near each other (ex. 1a and 1b)
- Semiperfect pairings are matches in which only one fuzzy wants to be near the other (ex 3a and 1b)
- Imperfect pairings are matches in which neither fuzzy wants to be with the other (ex. 3a and 3b)

### Your Challenge

Given a list of fuzzies:

1. Output the total number of perfect pairings. If there are any left:
2. Output the number of semiperfect pairings. If there are any left:
3. Output how many leftover bachelors there are.

Output and input format don't matter as long as you state them both.

### Test cases

```
1a, 1b:
1a and 1b are a perfect match
> 1 perfect, 0 semiperfect, 0 bachelors
1a, 2b, 2a, 3b:
1a and 2b are a perfect match
2a and 3b are a semiperfect match
> 1 perfect, 1 semiperfect, 0 bachelors
1a, 1b, 2a, 3a, 3b, 3b:
1a and 1b are a perfect match
2a and 3a are a perfect match
3b and 3b are an imperfect match
> 2 perfect, 0 semiperfect, 1 bachelor
1b, 2a, 3a
1b and 2a are a perfect match
3a is left over
(note: could also be:
2a and 3a are a perfect match
1b is left over
for the same result)
> 1 perfect, 0 semiperfect, 1 bachelor
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest in bytes wins.

Comment: Fuzzy? I think you mean [tribble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribble).

Answer (score 1):

## [The Most Wanted Prime Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239734/the-most-wanted-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

### Rotate two differently cased subwords independently

You have *one* string made of two subwords in different cases, the upper case first, then the lowercase:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

And you must return each subword *cycled* by a given increment. (N.b. the letters aren't rotated through the alphabet, but each character is shifted in the word)

The subwords are *not* always the same length as each other, and are part of the same 'data' structure. If your language cannot store strings, you're permitted to store the 'string' in a single array, e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']`

Here are the test cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 13 | 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm' |
| "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm", 13 | 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' |
| "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz", 26 | 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZopqrstuvwxyzn' |
| "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz", 13 | 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyz' |
| "ABCnopqrstuvwxyz", 2 | 'BCAyznopqrstuvwx' |
| "AAABBBcccddd", 2 | "BBAAABddcccd" |
| "AAABBBcccddd", 6 | "AAABBBcccddd" |
| "HELLOworld", 5 | 'LLOHErldwo' |
| "CODEgolf", 0 | 'CODEgolf' |

Here is an ungolfed example program:

```js
const subWordRotate = (original, rot) => [...original.split(/([A-Z]+)(?![A-Z][a-z]+)/)].map(list => [, ...list].reduce((memo, char, index, input) => {
  memo = memo.slice(0, input.length);
  memo.splice((index + rot) % (input.length), 1, char);
  return memo
}, Array(original.length).fill('')).join('')).join('')


const testCases = [
  ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 13],
  ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm", 13],
  ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz", 26],
  ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz", 13],
  ["ABCnopqrstuvwxyz", 2],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 2],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 3],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 4],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 5],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 6],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 7],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 8],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 9],
  ["AAABBBcccddd", 10],
  ["HELLOworld", 69],
  ["CODEgolf", 0]
]
testCases.forEach(
    testCase => console.log(`original: ${testCase[0]}, rotated by ${testCase[1]}: ${subWordRotate(...testCase)}`)
  );
```

---

Sandbox note: I think there is a bug in my code, such that `["AAABBBcccddd", 6],["AAABBBcccddd", 7],` return the same values. I think this is the same bug that is preventing me specifying how negative numbers work. Any help fixing the code would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Can we patch the corona certificate validation code (part 1/3)?

The new chancellor of Germany, Mr. Olaf Scholz, is in deep trouble: the Covid app does not show the vaccination status correctly beginning with booster vaccinations. He was not involved in the development of the app, since that was under chancellor Angela Merkel. He is now hiring you, Secret Agent 0x007, in order to understand the problem and later apply a strategy to fix the problem.

In step 1, Mr. Scholz wants to understand how the app has worked correctly when booster vaccinations were not even thought of. Mr. Scholz is an important person, so he has no time to read lengthy source code. Your code has to be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

These are the rules of valid vaccinations:

- There are 4 vaccination types in Germany: BioNTech (`B`), Moderna (`M`), Astra Zeneca (`A`) and Johnson&Johnson (`J`).
- A person is considered vaccinated 14 days after the necessary amount of injections.
- Biontech, Moderna and Astra Zeneca need 2 injections, Johnson needs 1 injection only.
- If 2 injections are needed, the second injection may occur earliest 28 days after the first injection.
- If 2 injections are needed, the second injection may only be with the same vaccination type.
- You get an entry in your vaccination pass which has the date in the format `YYMMDD`. COVID-19 is all post 2000, so we never need a 4 digit year.
- A full entry is in the form `YYMMDD X` followed by a newline, where `X` is the vaccination type.

How the application works:

You get the input in a reasonable form, e.g.

- from stdin, separated by newlines of your platform
- an array of strings (like `argv`)
- a function with variable number of arguments (like `...`)

The first line/entry is today's date, which you check the validity against. This comes from a time server, so it's always valid.
Each following line/entry is for one injection. There may be many of them, mainly limited by your platform (254 is certainly enough, also for part 2 and 3).

The application gives the following output:

- `injected` after a successful injection with the 14 days period not over
- `vaccinated` 14 days after the necessary amount of injections
- `manipulated` in case things do not match

`manipulated` takes precedence over `vaccinated` over `injected`. The output may contain arbitrary leading or trailing whitespace. A newline is not needed (it will be displayed in a mobile phone app textbox anyway).

The output can be

- on stdout
- the return value of the function

As there are quite some anti-vaxxers, the application checks for manipulations.

- Totally invalid vaccination types (like `Y`)
- Mix of vaccination types for the first and second injection
- More injections than needed
- Invalid date (like 200231 - there is no February 31st)
- Date too early (earlier than 200101, the beginning of the pandemic)
- Injection date later than today
- Injections in wrong order (second date before first date)

You don't need to consider:

- dates other than 6 digits
- characters in the date other than 0-9
- other character than space as the separator
- more than 1 character as vaccination type

Test cases:

```
<any date>
200231 X
= manipulated (invalid vaccination type)

<any date>
210301 B
210329 A
= manipulated (different vaccination types)

<any date>
210301 B
210329 B
210426 B
= manipulated (too many injections)

210814
210301 J
210814 J
= manipulated (too many injections)

<any date>
200231 B 
= manipulated (invalid date February 31st)

<any date>
191231 B 
= manipulated (date earlier than the pandemic)

210301
210302 J
= manipulated (date of the injection is tomorrow)
 
210301
210301 J
= injected (14 days not over)

210315
210301 J
= vaccinated (14 days over, only 1 injection needed)

210315
210301 B
= injected (14 days over, but 2 injections needed)

<any date>
210301 B
210302 B
= manipulated (28 days between 2 injections required)

210331
210301 B
210329 B
= injected (28 days between 2 injections, but not 14 days after the last one)

210412
210301 B
210329 B
= vaccinated (28 days between 2 injections, 14 days after the last one)

210412
210329 B
210301 B
= manipulated (injections in wrong order)
```

About realism: while this challenge has a realistic background, not all vaccination of rules in Germany are considered. Do not claim that your program can calculate the validity of a COVID-19 vaccination certificate.

Coming up:

- part 2, in which you need to consider booster vaccinations the wrong way
- part 3, in which you check whether you can patch the wrong code of part 2 to make it work correctly

I would appreciate if you participate in all 3 parts.

Comment: Regarding the process: I will start writing part 2 when I have received feedback on part 1. I will start writing part 3 when I received feedback on part 2. I want to release part 1 not before all 3 parts were reviewed. Would that be fine?

Comment: Interesting question, and I like it. The only thing that really sticks out to me is the input format, you should probably clarify before anybody asks - can you take input as an array/list of strings, rather than a newline delimited string? i.e. `["a", "b"]` instead of `"a\nb"`. It really doesn't matter much which you pick but since newline delimited strings would take more bytes for most langs, it's probably going to get asked immediately.

Comment: @Riker: thank you for the feedback. Yes, if that's a common thing to have for input, that's totally fine. Is there an example for a formulation considering all the common inputs?

Comment: I'm unsure if it counts as common, but yeah - it's just that indexing an array is probably shorter than calling `.split("\n")` for many languages, lol. Regarding posting 3 challenges, I think it's worthwhile to sandbox all 3 before posting any of course, but then posting maybe each one on sunday or something for 3 weeks would be fun. Somebody in chat compared it to a mini advent of code (golf) :)

Comment: I implemented this challenge (non-golfed) and all test cases work. I'll start working on the next one now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pluralize a Noun List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240398/pluralize-some-nouns)

Currently Closed

Comment: Can you change dropbox to github?

Comment: I can see if I can do that. Got some other big changes this thing probably needs though.

Comment: most users use Github

Comment: Got it. I realized that my lists of words were not particularly accurate, so as soon as I get better ones, I will switch to Github.

Comment: The link example fakehtpps://python.org can be [link](fakehtpps://python.org)

Comment: test-battery would be a good tag for this, I think

Comment: Now that this is posted, could you edit it down to a stub and delete it?

Answer (score 1):

## Minimal Randomness

In this challenge, you take input and shuffle the letters in a random, non-deterministic way which minimizes the probability that the output is different from the input.

### Rules

1. Your program must take input and use only substitution and transposition to randomly modify the input.
2. There must be a slight, non-zero probability that the output differs from the input.
3. Your program is graded based on the probability of its output differing from the input, with a lower probability being better.
4. If two programs are tied in score, the tie is settled by the code size, with a shorter code being better.
5. Your program must be non-deterministic.

### Meta

I'll post this to main soon unless there are any issues with it.

Comment: don't post it to main right away, wait for feedback and upvotes

Comment: yeah. That's what I meant, sorry if it sounded like "if nobody looks at this, it must be amazing!"

Comment: Seem a busy beaver and shuffle/next_permu, assuming it's possible to return differ

Answer (score 1):

## Short programs for fixed outputs

<sup>Inspired by [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)'s [Jelly puzzles](http://foldr.moe/jelly-puzzles/). Check them out if you're interested in practicing your Jelly skills</sup>

### Cops

The cops should choose three things:

- A freely available programming language,
- a byte count \$B\$, and
- a number of programs to write, \$n\$ (minimum 5)

They should then write \$n\$ programs, each of which:

- is exactly \$B\$ bytes long, and
- outputs a fixed, non-empty, non-whitespace output. That is, the output should contain at least one non-whitespace character. "Fixed" can mean that either:

  - it outputs the same thing no matter what input is provided, or
  - that it always outputs the same thing and takes no input.

  You may choose which of these meanings to take, but it must be the same for all \$n\$ programs. Please mention which of these options your programs use.

The cops should then reveal the following bits of information:

- The programming language used,
- the byte count \$B\$,
- any command line flags used for specific outputs,
- the \$n\$ outputs for each of the \$n\$ programs. If the outputs use any non-printable ASCII characters, please include a hexdump of the output.

The Robbers will be attempting to find \$B\$ byte long programs that output the same outputs, so you should keep your programs secret.

For example, if you choose to write 7 programs in Python, each of them 10 bytes, that output

> `4`, `True`, `2 3` , `1`, `72`, `!` and `[0]`

then you may have [these 7 programs](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eo07XVJMLwjSwMYQxjXSMYUxDTWUY00LLEsZUUlSCMaMNYjX//wcA) (one per line).

Robbers will crack one of your \$n\$ outputs if they can find any \$B\$ byte program in your language that has the same output. Note that the program does not have to be the same as the cop's program.

Any outputs that go a week without being cracked can be marked safe, and the programs for each output should be revealed. Until the program is revealed for a specific output, it can still be cracked.

You may post multiple answers, but each answer should be independent from all others. Your score is equal to the total number of safe outputs across all your answers. The user with the highest score wins.

### Robbers

You should find a Cops answer with at least one uncracked, unsafe output, and attempt to crack any of the outputs. That is, find a program that is exactly \$B\$ bytes long that outputs the same fixed output. Note that your program does not have to be the same as the Cop's original answer, just that the output has to be equal.

If you crack an answer, please do the following:

- Leave a comment on the Cop's answer, linking to either your answer or a TIO (or similar) link demonstrating the crack
- If this is your first crack, post an answer to the Robbers thread with your crack, linking to the relevant Cop answer
- For further cracks, edit them in to your existing answer, linking to the relevant Cop answer

A Robber's score is equal to the total number of cracks they make. The Robber with the highest score wins.

---

## Meta

- Thoughts? Feedback?
- Tags are [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard), [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). Any others?
- Is this a duplicate?

Comment: Other than the original inspiration, is there any reason to have multiple tasks in one cop submission? Since they're not related to each other and each one can be cracked individually, it seems like they should each be separate answers.

Answer (score 1):

## From code to golf ([Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241485/from-code-to-golf-cops-thread) and [Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241486/from-code-to-golf-robbers-thread))

Comment: Is allowed to remove letter?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Nope.

Comment: there will be someone say that the program are changed “239742387” times

Comment: @okie Then there will probably be some sort of pattern, and it'll be possible to find that.

Comment: @emanresuA yea and that will be another interesting part of this challenge.

Comment: @okie Exactly!!

Answer (score 1):

## Cell Evolution

Your lab needed to simulate how a particular cell evolves over time in a 2D grid space. A sample 2D grid space below shows a single cell at the centre of the grid.

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

The cell evolution follows these rules:

1. '0' indicates no live cell
2. A positive number indicates a live cell. The number indicates its age.
3. A cell will grow from age 1 to 5 in each evolution
4. After age 5, a cell will die at the next evolution (resetting to '0')
5. If a cell has 4 or more neighbours (adjacent and diagonally), it will die due to over-crowding.
6. In each evolution, a live cell will spread to its neighbour (adjacent and diagonally) if there is no live cell there and that neighbour is not overcrowded (surrounded by less than 4 cells)

Given an integer `n` in the input, which represents the size of the grid given, output the next generation of cells until all cells are dead ("0")

Extra rules:

1. The first live cell is always in the center of the grid
2. `n` must be odd so the live cell is always centered
3. The grid size <=9 to prevent incredibly large outputs of data

## Test case

Only 1 to save space in question

Input: 3

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
```

```
2 0 2
0 0 0
2 0 2
```

```
3 1 3
1 1 1
3 1 3
```

```
4 0 4
0 0 0
4 0 4
```

```
5 1 5
1 1 1
5 1 5
```

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

This is code-golf, so shortest bytes wins!

## Tags:

matrix

code-golf

ascii-art

cellular-automata

Please check the tags or edit them if they're wrong or you think a particular tag is not here. Feel free to comment on this puzzle!

Comment: What happens to the centre if `n` is even? Will there be 4 alive cells or 1? Where would the alive cell be placed?

Comment: The grid size must be odd so the live cell is always centered. Read the rules carefully @PyGamer0 u didnt read the extra rules

Comment: Could you include a test case to illustrate? Great idea btw.

Answer (score 1):

## Navigate the city

The government of your country has just completed a city designed to accommodate a few hundred thousand people. It has all sorts of facilities including roads, restaurants, malls, houses, etc. You have been invited to test the road system, but you are completely unfamiliar with it, so you need a GPS. Your challenge is to make one.

### Description of the city

*Note: when I say "a x a grid", I mean that there are a horizontal roads and a vertical roads within the grid.*

To make the challenge easier (because of course making a GPS is difficult in itself), the city is fixed. The city's road system is based on a very rigid grid. This grid is pictured further below.

The grid has a size of 15x15 and the roads are labeled as `[r/c num][dir]` where "r/c num" is the row/column number (whether it is a row or column depends on the direction of the road) and "dir" is the direction. If the road runs from west to east, "dir" is E, and if it runs from north to south, "dir" is S. For instance, "1E" is the first row of the grid, while "12S" is the twelfth column of the grid. Each row and column of the grid has a length of 14km (1km between each intersection).

The Central Business District (CBD) is the 5x5 sub-grid situated in the middle of the grid. Due to the traffic parameters set below, it is important for your GPS to route the user away from the CBD if it is not necessary to pass through that district. Note that the CBD includes the borders of the 5x5 sub-grid.

At each intersection, there is a traffic light. The amount of time to wait is as follows:

- there is a "base time" which is 400 if the intersection is in the CBD, and is the row position of the intersection (row 1 column 2 would be the intersection between 1E and 2S) times the column position otherwise;
- the waiting time to turn left is equal to the base time;
- the waiting time to go straight is equal to the base time, multiplied by 2;
- the waiting time to turn right is equal to the base time, multiplied by 3.

The times above are measured in seconds.

In addition to the standard grid of roads, there is an expressway circling the inner part of the city. It passes directly over parts of the 4E, 4S, 12E and 12S roads in such a way that it forms a square. In both directions, there is an innovative exit/entry elevator at each place where there would be an intersection if you took the 4E, 4S, 12E or 12S road rather than the expressway. It is positioned in such a way that you can skip the traffic light for that intersection and get going, and in addition to that you can turn your car around in whichever direction you would like and go that way. I know it sounds rather confusing, but in essence you can exit at any intersection and go whichever way you wish, with the distances still being measured in kilometers in all cases. Note that the elevator is instantaneous (once again, not very realistic, but who uses elevators for cars on the main road anyway?). Upon entering the expressway, you can go in either direction. On the expressway, there are no at-grade intersections, so the traffic is free-flowing, and there are no waits at traffic lights or any other obstruction. Entry onto the expressway is done at any intersection involving the 4E, 4S, 12E or 12S road. Cars entering the expressway do not need to wait at a traffic light before doing so. Once again, the way in which the entry elevator is designed ensures that all distances are still measured in kilometers. This means that you can drive 1km from an intersection, enter the expressway there, and drive 3km on the expressway, with the total distance being 4km.

The city sets speed limits as follows:

- 30 for all roads within the CBD;
- 60 for all standard roads outside the CBD;
- 120 for the expressway.

These speeds are measured in kilometers per hour.

### Picture of the grid

Everything inside, and including, the bold black outline, is the Central Business District. The blue outline represents the expressway.

[image]

### Challenge

Write a GPS which takes in a start intersection and end intersection, and attempts to output the fastest route from the start to the end. The "intersection" must be an intersection between two roads and can be specified in whichever reasonable input format you would like. You could take the row and column, the names of the two roads, etc. as long as it's reasonable.

Your output should be a list of directions in whichever reasonable output format you would like. Each direction should specify the direction to turn (straight, left, right, and for the expressway, enter/exit), the road to turn on and the number of "kilometers after the previous direction" to wait before executing this direction. For instance, "After 7km, exit the expressway onto 12E (East)". If the direction is to be executed while on the expressway, it must not take intersections into account. Your program may optionally decide to omit directions telling the user to "continue straight", but it may not omit any other direction. As shown above, directions telling the user to enter or exit an expressway must specify the direction to head upon entry ("enter the expressway (South)", for instance). You may direct the user in any direction from the starting intersection, and arrive at the end intersection from any side. It should also tell the user for how long he or she will have to drive, down to the second, and, optionally, the distance he or she will have to drive, which is necessarily measured in kilometers.

Your GPS may assume that the user will always be driving at the speed limit. It may also assume that the start and end are different.

### Scoring

There are 225 x 224 = 50400 ways to choose start/end pairs. Your GPS will be scored based on the sum of the amounts of time it takes to drive from the start to the end, for each pair of start/end points. The GPS with the smallest total is the winner.

In the unlikely event of a tie between two or more submissions, length of code shall be the tiebreaker.

No test cases because there is never a single route for any start/end pair.

---

The tags for this challenge are [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding), and [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid).

Answer (score 1):

## Play chess (KOTH)

Your task is to write a chess engine that will compete with other submissions in a chess tournament. Well, almost. Since writing a full engine can be a bit tedious, you only need to write the evaluation function.

An evaluation function takes a chessboard as input and returns how "favorable" the position is. If white is winning, the evaluation function should return a large positive number. If black is winning, a large negative number. If the situation is tied, a number close to zero.

Chess engines then simulate different possible games to some depth and choose the moves that lead to the best result.

A classic evaluation function is as follows:

- Set r=0
- For every white pawn, add 1. For every black pawn, subtract 1.
- Same for knights and bishops, except add or subtract 3.
- For rooks, use 5
- And for queens, use 9

This evaluation function only takes into account material advantage; that is, just the raw amount of different pieces. More complicated evaluation functions may consider the position of individual pieces, what kind of structures do the pawns form etc.

Your task is to write an evaluation function in C in at most 150 bytes. The evaluation function takes as input 7 bitboards. A bitboard is a 64-bit integer that assigns one bit to every square of the chessboard. The first bitboard has a bit set for every piece in the chessboard. The second one encodes the owner of the piece. The remaining bitboards have a bit set for every pawn, knight, bishop, rook and queen respectively. There is no bitboard for the king, since you can calculate it using the first and last 5 bitboards. Your function will return a signed integer.

For your convenience, I've aliased `__builtin__popcount` to `p` and `uint64_t` to `q`, and also included every standard header. You should name your function `e`.

Note that a slow evaluation function means that the engine won't be able to search as deep as with a fast one.

## TODO: more details... and also write the engine

## Meta

- Is 150 bytes a good number?
- Almost tempted to not alias the popcount... would have interesting results

Comment: How will this be KOTH if nobody actually competes in a game of chess?

Comment: @thejonymyster You write the evaluation function. A chess bot with your evaluation function competes (rest of the bot is standardized).

Comment: Oh, interesting!

Comment: @thejonymyster counts how many bits are set in a number. It's massively useful here, since the board data is in 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

## Count the ways to transform (2)

Your input is a matrix (2d array) of positive integers. For example:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 4 & 7\\
1 & 3 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}

A semi-continuous transformation of this matrix is a rearranging of elements that preserves immediate neighbors. For example, we can swap the \$2\$ in the bottom left, and the \$1\$ in the top left corner.

\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 4 & 7\\
1 & 3 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}

This is fine, because every number has the same neighborhood counts. That is, we can make a sorted list of numbers and their neighbors, and verify the they are the same:

\begin{matrix}
\text{Number} & \text{Neighbors} \\
1 & 1,1 \\
1 & 1,2,3 \\
1 & 1,3,4 \\
1 & 2,3,4 \\
2 & 1,1 \\
3 & 1,1,1,5 \\
4 & 1,5,7 \\
4 & 1,5,5 \\
5 & 3,4,4,6 \\
6 & 5,5,7 \\
7 & 4,6
\end{matrix}

Here is another example.

\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 4\\
\end{matrix}

Let's make a neighbor list. Note that we are gonna have duplicate entries (which is fine)

\begin{matrix}
\text{Number} & \text{Neighbors} \\
1 & 1,1 \\
1 & 1,1 \\
1 & 1,2,3 \\
1 & 1,2,3 \\
1 & 1,3,4 \\
1 & 1,3,4 \\
2 & 1,1 \\
3 & 1,1,1,1 \\
4 & 1,1 \\
\end{matrix}

Now, can we swap the top left \$2\$ and the bottom left \$1\$? It may look fine at first glance, but we must be careful! By swapping those two elements we would create a \$1\$ which has neighbors \$2,3,4\$, which didn't exist in the first input.

Just to demonstrate, here is the matrix after this non-semi-continuous transformation:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 4\\
\end{matrix}

And here is the neighbor list:

\begin{matrix}
\text{Number} & \text{Neighbors} \\
1 & 1,1 \\
1 & 1,1 \\
1 & 1,1,3 \\
1 & 1,2,3 \\
1 & 1,3,4 \\
1 & 2,3,4 \\
2 & 1,1 \\
3 & 1,1,1,1 \\
4 & 1,1 \\
\end{matrix}

Which is has changed after the transformation, ergo the transformation is non-semi-continuous (on this input).

To clarify, semi-continuity is a property of a transformation on some specific matrix.

Your code will take a matrix as input and output the number of (unique) semi-continuous transformations. Two transformations are different if the output is different. So for example swapping two identical numbers is the same as the identity transform (doing nothing).

Or in other words: Your code will take a matrix and return the number of matrices with those dimensions that have the same neighbor-list.

Answer (score 1):

## Climbing the Bookshelf [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Climbing the Bookshelf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242108/climbing-the-bookshelf)

Comment: Can we please have the option to output 0-indexed?

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## Alphabet Polygon

## Intro

Given a number of sides \$a\$ and a side length \$b\$, generate an \$a\$-sided polygon with side length \$b\$. The fill value will be the alphabet going clockwise. If there are not enough letters, wrap around.

## Test cases

````
3 4

     A
    H B
   I   C
  G F E D


4 4

ABCD
L  E
K  F
JIHG
```
````

Comment: This seems like it'd immediately run into problems with, say, a pentagon. But I digress, this is intriguing

Comment: Good idea, it's just that I'm unsure as to how one might handle a heptagon, or dodecagon, for instance. And do we have to loop back to the beginning of the alphabet once we have exhausted the entirety of the alphabet? For instance, a square with a side length of 10?

Answer (score 1):

## Trap the persistent hero in a maze

Last time a challenger tried to thwart your evil magical deeds, they got trapped in a maze that you created to be as small as possible, giving up only a few steps from the exit. Now there is another hero on the way. If it ain't broke, why fix it, so you ask the magic ball about the moves the hero will make in the maze. There are good news, and bad news.

The good news is that the hero's moves are still predictable. There is a list of moves, which determine how the hero moves in an intersection. The bad news is that the hero is persistent, never really giving up. What this means is that the list of moves repeats forever.

## TODO Explanation of the move list and rules

Your task is to write a program that traps the hero in the maze. You may assume that the input has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Count count count..** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241802/84844)

Comment: what about something like `[1,[2,5,10]]`

Comment: @thejonymyster count 1 to .. [2,5,10]->8 result is 7, ok I got it.. There's no test cases involving sorted lists, thanks

Comment: actually i was being stupid, but im glad you found use in it :D +1 btw

Comment: @thejonymyster glad you raised a doubt here on the sandbox ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Is this a Hamiltonian cycle?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241976/is-this-a-hamiltonian-cycle)

Answer (score 1):

### Shuffle up a list

Given two lists \$A\$ and \$B\$, with no repeats in elements and so that the elements of \$B\$ are identical to the elements of \$A\$ except for the order they are in, we say \$B\$ is an \$n\$-*well-shuffled list* of \$A\$ (where \$n\$ is a nonnegative integer) if:

- For any \$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in A^n\$, \$a_1\$'s position in \$A\$ is \$\neq\$ its position in \$B\$, \$a_2\$'s position in \$A\$ is \$\neq\$ its position in \$B\$, ... and \$a_n\$'s position in \$A\$ is \$\neq\$ its position in \$B\$
- For any \$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in A^n\$, if \$a_i\$ precedes \$a_j\$ for some \$(i, j) \in [1, n]^2\$ in \$A\$, then \$a_i\$ follows \$a_j\$ in \$B\$

Your task is to take two nonnegative integers \$m, n\$ as input and return how-many \$n\$-well-shuffled lists of lists of length \$m\$ there are.

Answer (score 1):

## [Decompress a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242397/decompress-a-ragged-list)

Answer (score 1):

## Is it an action?

[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Today, you will solve an abstract algebra challenge.

Consider a set \$G\$, which, to simplify things, is a finite subset of \$\mathbb{Z}\$ containing \$0\$. It has a binary operation \$*\$, which for our example will be \$+\$, but your program should be able to handle any binary operation. If \$G\$ is closed under \$*\$, i.e. \$g * g' \in G \forall g, g' \in G\$, there is associativity with regard to \$*\$, there is a unique element in \$G\$, which we will note as \$1_G\$, such that \$1_G * g = g * 1_G = g \forall g \in G\$, and there exists a unique \$g^{-1} \in G \forall g \in G\$ such that \$ g * g^{-1} = g^{-1} * g = 1_G \$, then \$G\$ is a *group*.

Consider a set \$X\$, which is also a finite subset of \$\mathbb{Z}\$. Then \$\circ: G \times X \to X\$, where \$G\$ is a group, is an *action* if:

- \$1_G \circ x = x \forall x \in X\$, and
- \$g \circ (g' \circ x) = (g * g') \circ x \forall g, g' \in G, x \in X\$ (associativity).

### Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which takes in the following:

- \$G\$, a finite subset of \$\mathbb{Z}\$ that includes \$0\$;
- \$X\$, also a finite subset of \$\mathbb{Z}\$, but not necessarily the same as \$G\$;
- a binary operation \$*\$ that operates within \$G\$ and that makes \$(G, *)\$ a group, which can be taken in any reasonable manner you would like, such as taking it as a function with two parameters, and
- an "application" \$\circ\$ from \$G \times X\$ to \$X\$, which can be taken in any reasonable manner you would like.

For the purposes of this challenge, \$1_G\$ is always \$0\$.

This program should then output true if \$\circ\$ is an action and false if not. You may use any two distinct values for true and false.

The shortest code, measured in bytes, wins.

#### Test cases.

\$G = \{0, 1, 2\}\$

\$X = \{1, 2, 3\}\$

\$*\$ defined by \$g * g' = (g + g') mod 3\$

\$\circ\$ defined by \$g \circ x = g + x\$

Output: **false** because:

- \$1_G\$ is 0;
- then \$1_G \circ x = 0 \circ x = 0 + x = x\$;
- but \$(1 * 2) \circ 2 = 0 \circ 2 = 2 \neq 1 + (2 + 2) mod 3 = 1 + (2 \circ 2) = 1 \circ (2 \circ 2)\$, thus \$\circ\$ is not associative.

\$G = \{0, 1, 2\}\$

\$X = \{0, 1, 2\}\$

\$*\$ defined by \$g * g' = (g + g') mod 3\$

\$\circ\$ defined by \$g \circ x = (g + x) mod 3\$

Output: **true** because:

- \$1_G\$ is 0;
- then \$1_G \circ x = 0 \circ x = (0 + x) mod 3 = x mod 3 = x\$ (because \$x < 3\$);
- and \$\circ\$ is associative (proof not provided)

Answer (score 1):

## Quicksand

In this [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, you take a positive integer as input, which represents the height of a sand pile, located at (0,0) on an infinite square grid. For example, if our input is `123`, the sand grid looks initially like this:

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &123& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

Now, piles of sand are unstable, so they topple if their height is 4 or greater. When sand piles topple, they send sand equally in all four directions, but due to the quantum nature of sand, the amount sent is an integer. Or in other words, if there is a pile of height `n`, it sends sand as follows:

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor & 0 \\
\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor & n\mod 4 & \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor \\
0 & \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor & 0
\end{matrix}\$

This means that sandpiles evolve step by step. For example, if we have this initial position, here's how the sandpiles evolve.

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

Now, since all the sandpiles have less than 4 sand, this sand grid is stable.

## Rules

Your task is to take an positive integer \$i\$ as input, and output the eventually stable grid that the following initial position evolves to:

### Todo add cool fractals

\$\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\$

(Note that the grid is still infinitely big)

The output format should be the following: "width;data", where width is an odd number representing the width a square that bounds the eventually stable arrangement (width doesn't have to be the smallest possible). Next is the raw data, which is just the square section of the grid flattened, and the numbers are represented with digits "0123"

Comment: by "IO format" do you mean input or output? if its input, i dont understand why youd take the ending width as an input. great pun btw

Answer (score 1):

[Bracket Depth List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242382/bracket-depth-list)

Comment: (Because I suspect a lot of people are going to use regex) can we take other bracket pairs and what formats are acceptable for string output?

Comment: wdym by other bracket pairs?

Answer (score 1):

### Word Guess KOTH

Inspired by [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) and [Evil Wordle](https://swag.github.io/evil-wordle/).

A King of the Hill game where you must write a bot which acts as both Guesser and Judge of a word guessing game. Each bot will play a match against all the other bots.  Each match will consist of 10 rounds alternating between judge and guesser.  A bot's score for the match is the number of guesses the opponent made minus the number of guesses it made.  Higher is better. Bot with the highest average *[or total?]* score is KOTH.

The game is as follows:

1. The Judge and Guesser are both provided with the same dictionary of N letter words.
2. The Judge selects an answer from the dictionary.
3. The Guesser makes a guess. The candidate word must be contained in the dictionary.
4. The Judge is given the guess, and provides a score according to the following rules.

- The score is a string of N characters from the set ['G','O','B'], corresponding to the guessed letters

  - A 'G' indicates that the guessed letter is correct for that position. Great
  - A 'O' signifies that the guessed letter is in that answer but not that position. Out-of-place.
  - A 'B' indicates that the guessed letter is not in the answer.  Bad.
- If a letter appears in the guess more than once, there will never be more non-'B' results than instances of that letter in the answer.

  - for example if the answer is 'ruler' and the guess is 'belle', the score will be 'BOGBB'.

4. Steps 2 and 3 continue until the score is all 'G's.
5. The the number of guesses is added to the Judge's score and subtracted from the Guesser's.

- Note that the judge is free to modify the answer after each guess, as long as the new answer is consistent with all the previous guesses.

An example scoring function in Python is:

```
def count_score(truth, trial):
    score = [None]*len(truth)
    allow = truth
    for index,value in enumerate(trial):
        if truth[index]==value:
            score[index]='G'
            allow=allow.replace(value,'',1)
        for index,value in enumerate(trial):
        if not score[index]:
            if value in allow:
                score[index]='O'
                allow=allow.replace(value,'',1)
            else:
                score[index]='B'
    return ''.join(score)
```

Entries must provide a bot command that can be called from the command line and prints the required outputs to stdout, separated by newlines.

For all the use cases below, `codex` is a filepath to a dictionary of legal words, and `token` is a
string used by a bot to maintain state. It must not be empty. The token generated in any round is passed back to the same bot in the following round.  The opponent bot will never see your token. Tokens are not retained from one round to the next.

*arguments --> results*

`codex "judge" --> token`
Judge initialization. Returns a token.

`codex "judge" token trial --> token score`
Judge will score the `trial` word.  `score` is constructed according to the rules above.

`codex "guess" --> token trial`
Guesser makes initial `trial` guess.

`codex "guess" token score - token trial`
Guesser gets `score` from previous guess. Returns new `trial` guess.

**Example Bot:**

```
import random,sys,re

def begin_offer(codex):
    words = [l.strip() for l in open(codex)]
    return [random.choice(words)]

def score_trial(token, trial):
    return token, count_score(token,trial)

def first_guess(codex):
    words = sorted([l.strip() for l in open(codex)])
    guess = words[0]
    return (guess, guess)

def later_guess(codex, prior, score):
    words = sorted([l.strip() for l in open(codex)])
    index = words.index(prior)
                  
    for place,value in enumerate(score):
        if value != 'G':
            while words[index][place]==prior[place]:
                index+=1
            break
    guess = words[index]
    return guess,guess


if __name__ == "__main__":
    codex,style,*extra = sys.argv[1:]
    if style == 'judge':
        if not extra:
            result = begin_offer(codex)
        else:
            result = score_trial(*extra)
    elif style == 'guess':
        if not extra:
            result = first_guess(codex)
        else:
            result = later_guess(codex,*extra)

    print("\n".join(result))
```

**Match Runner** (in progress)

```
import sys,subprocess
def reply_split(reply):
    return [bites.decode('ascii').strip() for bites in reply.split()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    judge,guess = sys.argv[1:]

    reply = subprocess.check_output([judge, "words.txt", "judge"])
    judge_token,*trash = reply_split(reply)

    reply = subprocess.check_output([guess, "words.txt", "guess"])
    guess_token,trial = reply_split(reply)

    for round in range(10):

        print(trial)
    
        reply = subprocess.check_output([judge, "words.txt", "judge", judge_token, trial])
        judge_token,score,*trash = reply_split(reply)

        print(score, "\n")
        if score == 'GGGGG':
            print("{} guessed {}'s word in {} rounds".format(guess, judge, round+1))
            break
        
        reply = subprocess.check_output([guess, "words.txt", "guess", guess_token, score])
        guess_token,trial,*trash = reply_split(reply)

    print(round+1)
```

Comment: I wrote up all the sample code for this before I found [this related post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24269/152) where the comments suggest a similar KOTH

Comment: Question: Is EVERY string of N characters allowed to be returned by your function?

Comment: @StackMeterPlus no, see steps 1-3

Comment: Although it's not an exact dupe, this feels quite similar to some other KotHs that are based around guessing numbers or playing games like hangman.

Comment: Step 2 may be misleading and suggest that there is a slight chance of guessing the word in the first guess. In the adversarial Wordle I know ([by qntm](https://qntm.org/files/absurdle/absurdle.html)) the underlying word is chosen only after the guess, along with returned score (so that they are consistent). This way there is no way to guess a word in the first try (for a reasonable Judge). Or maybe current formulation is intentional?

Answer (score 1):

## [Generate all groupings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242783)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238395/fully-matched-numbers)

Comment: Can we output in reverse order? This order feels a bit unnatural

Answer (score 1):

## [Bigger regex?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242769/is-it-a-bigger-regex)

Comment: anttiP you can clear this post now buddy

Answer (score 1):

[Triangle Tripler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242726/triangle-tripler)

Answer (score 1):

## Very simple auto battler

There are two players. Each player has a team of between 0 and 5 members. Each member has two relevant statistics: an attack score and a health score. These range from 1 to 50.

Until at least one team runs out of members, you need to battle the lead member of each team against each other. (You can decide whether this is the first or last member of the team.) The two attacks are simultaneous, so it's possible that both members can defeat each other. Each attack reduces the foe's health by the user's attack. Once a team member's health is reduced to zero (or less) then it faints and takes no part in the rest of the battle.

If both teams simultaneously run out of unfainted members then the result is a draw otherwise the team that still has unfainted members wins.

Your task, given two teams in a reasonable format, e.g. list of tuples of `(health, attack)`, is to write a program or function that outputs which (if any) team will win, using one of three specific values of your choice, e.g. `-1`, `0` and `1`, or `A`, `B` and `D`. (Please describe the mapping of values in your answer.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

[Sample team generator and battler](https://tio.run/##bY/RasMgGIXvfYrT3EwhC3awXZRl0LIH2H3IxS@xVEiMGEfo02eatE23DgR/zzmfHt05nHr7Mk2mc70P8GSbvmONPs5j0NRxsWNAmlCiquM8nkyrL9EibcYGLnO8CXyg1Zan8EwtXEHOadvw6g@yzfEqRY5/5VpE3uvw7e18CWMU319LMfX76Hxkke2fhjm@y3LQVTzciYot9QmRhUotqZJ1XHguodK4TZ9Uq0g30Rxv4fcScvkiFa53XIrFVw@@uvqJTtKl1VdLZ@2xx2jssMmYbhP@GDisgUHf2Z@exk02TT8)

Answer (score 1):

## Interpret Subleq code

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

### Background

Subleq is a language that has only one 3 argument instruction.  The instruction has three operands `A B C`. When executed it subtracts the contents in address `A` from address `B`; stores the result in address `B`; if the result is less than or equal to 0 it goes to address `C`.  -1 in a position has special meaning.  -1 in `A` will read the ASCII value of then next character of input into `B`; if no more input then goto 'C'. -1 in `B` will send the ASCII character in `A` to output.  -1 in `C` will exit the program instead of going to an address.

### Task

Given input and Subleq code, output the results from running the Subleq code.

An interpreter built in Excel is [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnifb6P01c9pbdyYm?e=7b9vHa).

### Rules

- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test Cases

For the test cases below, any input to the Subleq is before the '/', code is after.  Code is represented by decimal numbers.

#### Hello, World!

```
Input=>
/
12 -1 13
1 0 6
3 2 -1
4 4 0
72 101 108 108 111 42 32 87 111 114 108 100 33
Output
Hello, World!
```

#### [!I!n!s!e!r!t! !i!n!b!e!t!w!e!e!n!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225410/101349)

```
Input->
1 2 3 4 5 6/
2 -1 33
-1 8 -1
8 -1 0
8 8 
Output
!1! !2! !3! !4! !5! !6!
```

### Meta

- What am I leaving out?
- Is there a better way of handling the input to the Subleq code?
- Does it need more/better examples?

Answer (score 1):

[Knights Jam | Chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242934/knights-jam-chess)

Answer (score 1):

[Factorials of primes decomposition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243029/factorials-of-primes-decomposition)

Comment: Are duplicate prime numbers allowed? (is `36 = 3#3 3#-1` or `36 = 3#1 3#1` valid?)

Comment: i guess i could allow duplicate prime no.'s. Which do you think benefits the challenge more @AnttiP?

Comment: Allowing duplicates makes the challenge a bit easier, since you don't have to simplify the exponents. Basically without duplicates there are two parts to the program, one is the recursion part (factor to primes and recurse) and the other one is the simplification. If duplicates are allowed, then simplification is not necessary so the answers will be shorter. Personally I *slightly* prefer allowing duplicates, since the answers would be a bit more "focused". But I think if you allow duplicates then you should also allow a 0 exponent.

Comment: I think the challenge should be ready to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Play 1D minesweeper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243289/play-1d-minesweeper)

Comment: What should I output?

Answer (score 1):

## [Page Selector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243701/page-selector)

Comment: Personally, I think that the last two examples (from a UI standpoint) should be `< 1 2 3 [4] 5 ... 11 >` and `< 1 ... 6 [7] 8 ... 11 >`.  Regardless, you should clarify if there is some priority for how numbers should be distributed (e.g. should the center have more numbers?)

Comment: Slightly related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147318/goto-the-nth-page

Comment: Adding to AnttiP's comment, a worked out example or examples would be nice.

Comment: @AnttiP Good point, clarified slightly.

Comment: What should be the output for `11 6 7`? `< 1 ... 6 [7] ... 11 >` or `< 1 ... [7] 8 ... 11 >` or something else? (this should be clarified in the specs)

Comment: @pajonk Clarified.

Comment: Ok, what about `11 6 6`? (That problem with specs was intended in my previous comment)

Comment: @pajonk Added (and updated specs)

Answer (score 1):

## Reveal all clues of Black Box

Black Box is a board game, Your task is to reveal all clues.

### What is black box

Black box is a board game with hidden atoms, Your task is given input, All atoms, reveal all clues.

### I/O

#### Input

The atoms can be any 1-char that is not newline (Used for separator) Like this.

```
O....
...O.
..O..
.....
....O
```

#### Output

When the code reveals all clues (See Below) the output of The given input above can be:

```
 HRHH1
H     1
R     H
H     H
2     R
H     H
 H2HRH
```

or

```
[["H", "R", "H", "H", "1"], ["1", "H", "H", "R", "H"], ["H", "R", "H", "2", "H"], ["H", "2", "H", "R", "H"]]
```

Ignore the number, This doesn't mean anything, the number can be non-unique

### Task

#### Hit

Atoms interact with rays in three ways. A direct impact on an atom by a ray is a "hit".

```
.........
.........
.O.....O.
.........
.........
...O.....H 1
.........
.......O.
```

Thus, ray 1 fired into the box configuration at left strikes an atom directly, generating a "hit", designated by an "H". A ray which hits an atom does not emerge from the box.

### Deflection

The interaction resulting from a ray which does not actually hit an atom, but which passes directly to one side of the ball is called a "deflection". The angle of deflection for this ray/atom interaction is 90 degrees. Ray 2 is deflected by the atom at left, exiting the box as shown.

```
    2
.........
.........
.O.....O.
.........
.........2
...O.....
.........
.......O.
```

#### Reflection

The final type of interaction of a ray with an atom is a "reflection", designated by an "R". This occurs in two circumstances. If an atom is at the edge of the grid, any ray which is aimed into the grid directly beside it causes a reflection.

```
.........
.........
.O.....O.
.........
.........
...O.....
.........
.......O.
      RHR
      354
```

Rays 3 and 4 at left would each generate a reflection, due to the atom at the edge. Ray 5 would be a hit on the atom.

#### Double deflection

The other circumstance leading to a reflection is when two deflections cancel out. In the grid at left, ray 6 results in a reflection due to its interaction with the atoms in the grid.

```
   6

   R
.....
..O.O
.....
.....
.....
```

#### Detour

Rays that don't result in hits or reflections are called "detours". These may be single or multiple deflections, or misses. A detour has an entry and an exit location, while hits and reflections only have an entry location for a hit, and a single entry/exit location for a reflection.

```
  8   8  
.........
.........
.O.....O.
.........9
.........
...O.....
.........9
.......O.
```

Of course, more complex situations result when these behaviors interact. Ray 8 results in two deflections, as does ray 9.

Some rays travel a twisted course, like ray 1 at left.

```
 .........
 .........
 .O.....O.
 .........
1.........
 ...O.....
 .........
 .......O.
     1
```

Notice that this complex set of five deflections above looks exactly like a single deflection, as shown by ray 2 at left. Things are not always as simple as they seem within a black box.

```
 .........
 .........
 .........
 .....O...
1.........
 .........
 .........
 .........
     1
```

Reflections and hits can be more complex, too. Ray 2 gets deflected by the first atom, reflected by the next two atoms and again deflected by the original atom, yielding a reflection.

```
.O...
.....R 2
.....
.O.O.
.....
```

Ray 3 below gets deflected by the first atom, then by the second atom, and then hits the third atom, yielding a hit.

```
   ...O.
   O....
   .....
3 H.....
   ...O.
```

### Test cases

```
O....
...O.
..O..
.....
....O
->
 HRHH1
H     1
R     H
H     H
2     R
H     H
 H2HRH

O
->
 H
H H
 H

OOO
O O
OOO
->
 HHH
H   H
H   H
H   H
 HHH

..O..
O...O
..O..
->
 HRHRH
R     R
H     H
R     R
 HRHRH

...
...
...
->
 123
4   4
5   5
6   6
 123

....
O...
...O
....
->
 H1HH
R    1
H    R
R    H
2    R
 HH2H
```

### Meta:

- Any feedback?

Comment: I think I would first explain what Black Box is and then specify the task and I/O. Right now the Input and Output sections are hard to grasp without context and one needs to go back to those sections after reading specs.

Comment: I'd use a capital O in your demos, rather than a #. It makes it visually clearer, imo.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ok, I will do later

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It's a bit ugly because the clues are letters, I will rollback if someone doesn't like this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Can the Tune be Played?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243727/can-the-tune-be-played)

I changed the question slightly from when it was posted on the Sandbox.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you explain in detail eg. the `[1, 3, 2] is valid - the notes would be played in the order [3, 1, 2]` statement?

Comment: I might change the wording because I think I have explained it in a confusing way. A more mathematical explanation is: if you shift back each number n in a list by n spaces, do any of the numbers end up in the same space? If so, the list is invalid. So: shifting 1 back by 1 space, it ends up at position -1; shifting 3 back by 3 spaces, it ends up at position -2, and shifting 2 back by 2 spaces, it ends up at position 0. Since none of these are the same position, the list [1, 3, 2] is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [The Nineteenth Bakery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/243895/107299)

Answer (score 1):

## [Negative of an ASCII photo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/244176/110555)

Comment: interesting challenge although this might be a dupe im not sure

Comment: @DialFrost I had a browse and couldn't find one, but obviously if it is I won't post

Comment: ah ic although u might wanna state that the negative photo has to be of same "size" as the original one as suggested by ur ["#",""] and ["","#"] but i dont know if it rly matters

Answer (score 1):

## Overlay the Ukrainian Flag

A pseudo-sequel to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/draw-the-ukrainian-flag).

### The Challenge

As of the posting of this challenge, my PFP has a blue-and-yellow overlay in support of Ukraine. Your task is to, given the path to an input image, overlay a similar image on top.

Here is the flag:
[image: Ukrainian Flag]

- The flag is divided horizontally across the middle into two equally sized stripes.
- Stripe colors: `(0, 87, 183)` or `#0057B7` (blue, top) and `(255, 215, 0)` or `#FFD700` (yellow, bottom).
- You must, given the path to an image as input, overlay two semi-transparent rectangles of those colors onto it. The rectangles must each take up half the vertical area of the image, and be as wide as the image.
- The rectangles must have 70% opacity.
- Colors must be exact if possible, otherwise use the closest available blue and yellow.
- The image can be saved to a file or piped raw to STDOUT in any common image file format, or it can be displayed in a window.
- If you're saving to a file, you may either overwrite the old image or create a new one.
- Built-in flag images, flag-drawing libraries, or [horrendously upscaling the Ukrainian flag emoji](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60681392#60681392) are prohibited.

Comment: Can we choose the input file format or you have some restrictions on that? Do we have to input via a path to file or other means of inputting graphics is fine (raw bytes, 3D array of RGB values etc.)? May we assume the image has even height (in pixels or in some convenient unit)?

Answer (score 1):

## Overlay Two Images

This challenge is as simple as it gets: Just take two images as input (in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges)) and overlay the first atop the second.

- The overlay must have 70% opacity (if possible, if not use the closest available analog), or in other words, multiply the overlay's pixel values by 0.3 and the base by 0.7.
- The overlay must be centered over the base image.
- If the overlay is bigger, it must be cropped to fit within the base.
- If the base image is bigger, the overlay does *not* need to be enlarged.

Comment: Maybe you could explain wat 70% opacity actually means.

Comment: @mathcat 70% of the pixels are transparent or have an alpha value of 70? Then I guess if you take a sample on the final image the colour should be `top_red*0.3+bottom_red*0.7`, `top_blue*0.3+bottom_blue*0.7`,`top_green*0.3+bottom_green*0.7`... or however colours work

Comment: I think adding [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60753789#60753789) would be important

Answer (score 1):

## [Optimally break a string into substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246107/optimally-break-a-string-into-words)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

Comment: What do we need to optimize?  if it's "smallest number of pieces", then `[potato][c][a][r][rot]` also scores 5.

Comment: @Nitrodon Yeah it's smallest number of pieces, forgot to add that.

Comment: Could we please have a few more testcases?

Comment: @ophact Sure, I'll add some

Comment: Title suggestion: "substrings" -> "words" (as the substrings in question, other than single characters, have to come from a dictionary of sorts)

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplified Piet Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246224/simplified-piet-interpreter)

Comment: 1) Long challenges are fine, especially when the challenge is complex like this. Complete specification is much more important. 5) From quick skimming, the example looks mostly correct to me, **except:** at the pointer instruction near the start, right + clockwise 9 times is down, not up. An easy fix is to change the initial number to, say, 7. 6) My choice would be to add something like "Reference: official Piet specification (link)" at the bottom.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks for the feedback! For the example, I think I just mixed up clockwise and counterclockwise lol.

Comment: Seems interesting!! I'd say my one complaint is that this does miss the other big feature of Piet, which is that instructions are defined by the *difference* between the blocks you're travelling between, not the specific value of either of them, although that is probably acceptable for simplicity reasons. Also should provide some specifics on how the final output is to be formatted.

Comment: @des54321 Yeah, I decided to remove the hue and lightness aspect of Piet because I thought that it would add unnecessary complexity to the challenge, though if you think that it would make the challenge more interesting, I could add that aspect to the challenge as well.

Comment: @AidenChow the hue/lightness feature would definitely make an interesting (if possibly harder) challenge, and the instruction set you have now would fit nicely in a 3 hue 3 lightness cycle, but its certainly ultimately your decision whether to include it

Comment: @des54321 I will think about it. The problem is that if I were to change the specs now, I would have to completely rewrite my worked example.

Answer (score 1):

## [Draw the Norwegian flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246270/draw-the-norwegian-flag)

Comment: link is wrong. [correct link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/draw-the-ukrainian-flag)

Comment: @Steffan oh wow, never knew stack exchange was that stubborn

Comment: I don't think it would [be](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149842) [considered](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64140) a duplicate [as](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40052) [there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52667) [are](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52615) [already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223915/) [tons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52643) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136927) [flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194299) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18664)

Comment: Perhaps it's not considered a duplicate, but I'd hold the opinion that printing the Norwegian flag isn't particularly interesting, only *because* many flag challenges already do exist (or maybe this is the unpopular opinion and many people enjoy having these flag challenges).

Answer (score 1):

## [Draw New Posts' Profile!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246718/draw-new-posts-profile)

Comment: @DLosc Whoops, fixed.

Comment: Also possibly loosen the input from boolean to any two distinct values? Although that might make it too easy if someone specifies the inputs to be their lang's color values for blue/black

Comment: Also presumably this is [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @des54321 of course

Comment: As this image is 48x48 and binary in nature, I suggest embedding in the post a binary matrix reflecting on/off pixels of the picture.

Comment: Note that NP and SP's profile pictures are slightly "blurred", they are not perfect 48×48 pixel images. So you might want to clarify any non-white pixels are the same blue/black.

Answer (score 1):

## Create a program that may or may not determine if a list is in this sequence

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Your task is to write a program which returns another program which has a nonzero chance of correctly determining if an inputted list is in a sequence described below. This can either be done through randomly generating a program, which will occasionally do the correct task, or through hardcoding a program that always works and returning that.

### The sequence

The sequence you'll need to identify starts with the following items:

*well the sequence I was gonna use turns out to have a closed form formula so frick*

Comment: What was the idea here? Was it going to be something uncomputable? Could this still be salvaged with a new sequence? Also, what stops you from submitting like `print(random(0,1))` or whatever

Comment: @thejonymyster Basically, you try to write a program that will randomly generate (sometimes) executable code. So there's a very small chance you'll get something which actually does solve the problem (checking if something's in a sequence, in this case), which is longer than the program which randomly generated it.

Answer (score 1):

## Binary Palindromes

Take an input of a positive integer and determine if the binary representation of that number is palindromic. Except for 0 (which is not in the scope of this problem), all binary palindromes are odd, so you do not have to worry about leading/trailing zeroes.

OEIS Sequence: https://oeis.org/A006995

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

```
1 -> True (1)
4 -> False (100)
85 -> True (1010101)
131 -> False (10000011)
```

Comment: I personally think this question is trivial, but I may be wrong so I didn't downvote it.

Comment: take this as an answer, `str(bin(n))[2:][::-1]==str(bin(n))[2:]`

Comment: Very closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216929/based-palindromes. May even be considered duplicate by some? Better wait for input from other users and/or ask in chat.

Comment: Didn't see that one because I searched specifically for binary. Will ask in chat.

Answer (score 1):

## [Make an Apartment Building](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247470/apartment-building)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Answer (score 1):

## [Is it a good chord?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247191/is-it-a-good-chord)

Answer (score 1):

## [LOOOOONG TEEEEEXT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247512)

Comment: How do you determine what a *vowel* is?  I assume the question cares about *letters* not phonemes, so is it `aeiou`?  You test cases imply that `y` and `w`, which are sometimes vowel letters, are not treated as vowel however is this a universal?

Comment: Oops, guess I should specify that...

Answer (score 1):

## King of the Hill: Greed Control

### What is Greed Control

Greed control is a **multiplayer** `round-based` game
in which in every round, a player bet a number inside
a specific range, say 1~100. Say 2 people betted 100,
then they'd both get 100/2 which is `50` points    in
the game. **Basically, the players that choose the same
number split the scores evenly (no rounding) and the
total of their net score gain is the number they
chose**.

After a set number of rounds, players compare scores.
The highest score generally wins the game overall.

### Your challenge

Build a bot in `python`, specifically, `python 3`   ,
that when given input, discussed in the section `input`,
they give the number as an integer they bet as output.
It must be a`function`.

### Input

`information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num`.
`information` is a dictionary with integer keys
in which each key's value is the number of bots
that chose that key's number **last round**.
`points` is the list of integers you can choose from.
`round_number` is the round number.
`sum_of_all` is like `information`, except it is
the summation of **all rounds**.
`user_num` is the number of players playing.

### We guarantee that

We guarantee that `points` stay the same every round
and is strictly increasing, all integers. However,
it may not be consecutive.

### Controller function

```python
from random import choice

def random_better(information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num):
    return choice(points)

def greedy_better(information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num):
    return points[-1]

def calculator(information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num):
    return sorted(points, key=lambda x:x/(information[x]+0.000000000001))[0]

def smarty(information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num):
    return sorted(points, key=lambda x:x/(information[x]+0.000000000001))[choice(range(1,40))]

users = [random_better, greedy_better, calculator, smarty] * 10

user_names = [user.__name__.replace('_',' ') for user in users]
rounds = 1000
points = sorted(list(range(1,101)))
user_num = len(users)
bots = [user for user in users]
scores = [0.0 for user in users]
information = {i:0 for i in points}
sum_of_all = {i:0 for i in points}
print('\n'*100)

for round_number in range(rounds):
    choices = [bot(information, points, round_number, sum_of_all, user_num) for bot in bots]
    information = {score:choices.count(score) for score in points}
    scores = [scores[index] + choices[index]/information[choices[index]] for index in range(user_num)]

    print(f'\n\n\nRound #{round_number+1} Reports: ')

    print('\nBots Report: ')
    print('\n'.join([f'{user_names[index].ljust(20)} '
                     f'chose {choices[index]} '
                     f'and got {choices[index]/information[choices[index]]} additional points, '
                     f'making it now have {scores[index]} points!!! ' for index in range(user_num)]))

    print('\nDistribution Report: ')
    print('\n'.join([f'The number of bots who chose {num} is: {information[num]}!!! ' for num in points]))

    print('\nLeaderboard Report: ')
    sorted_list = sorted(range(user_num), key=lambda x: -scores[x])

    print(f'\n{user_names[sorted_list[0]].ljust(20)} with {scores[sorted_list[0]]} points, '
          f'\n{user_names[sorted_list[1]].ljust(20)} with {scores[sorted_list[1]]} points, and'
          f'\n{user_names[sorted_list[2]].ljust(20)} with {scores[sorted_list[2]]} points!!! ')

    sum_of_all = {i:sum_of_all[i]+information[i] for i in points}

print('\n\n\nFinal Report Card: \n')
print('\n'.join([f'{user_names[sorted_list[index]].ljust(20)}: '
                 f'{scores[sorted_list[index]]} points. ' for index in range(user_num)]))
```

The first part is imports. You may only depend
on default python built-ins or the python standard
library. Or if you manage to hide it and I out of
coincidence have the package...

The second part is your functions. Naming your function
`bot_name_with_underscores`
is encouraged.

The third part are game parameters.
The number of rounds, the accessible outputs,
etc.

The fourth part is **running the program**!!!

An example output is as follows:

```
Round #1 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 3 and got 1.5 additional points, making it now have 1.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 10.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 1.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 3 and got 1.5 additional points, making it now have 1.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 2!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 10.0 points, 
random better        with 1.5 points, and
smarty               with 1.5 points!!! 



Round #2 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 7 and got 7.0 additional points, making it now have 8.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 15.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 2.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 6.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 2!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 15.0 points, 
random better        with 8.5 points, and
smarty               with 6.5 points!!! 



Round #3 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 4 and got 4.0 additional points, making it now have 12.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 25.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 3.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 2 and got 2.0 additional points, making it now have 8.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 25.0 points, 
random better        with 12.5 points, and
smarty               with 8.5 points!!! 



Round #4 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 6 and got 6.0 additional points, making it now have 18.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 35.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 4.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 2 and got 2.0 additional points, making it now have 10.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 35.0 points, 
random better        with 18.5 points, and
smarty               with 10.5 points!!! 



Round #5 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 2 and got 2.0 additional points, making it now have 20.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 45.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 5.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 6 and got 6.0 additional points, making it now have 16.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 45.0 points, 
random better        with 20.5 points, and
smarty               with 16.5 points!!! 



Round #6 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 3 and got 3.0 additional points, making it now have 23.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 55.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 6.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 2 and got 2.0 additional points, making it now have 18.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 55.0 points, 
random better        with 23.5 points, and
smarty               with 18.5 points!!! 



Round #7 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 8 and got 8.0 additional points, making it now have 31.5 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 10.0 additional points, making it now have 65.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 7.0 points!!! 
smarty               chose 3 and got 3.0 additional points, making it now have 21.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 1!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 65.0 points, 
random better        with 31.5 points, and
smarty               with 21.5 points!!! 



Round #8 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 1 and got 0.5 additional points, making it now have 32.0 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 70.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 0.5 additional points, making it now have 7.5 points!!! 
smarty               chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 26.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 2!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 2!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 70.0 points, 
random better        with 32.0 points, and
smarty               with 26.5 points!!! 



Round #9 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 3 and got 3.0 additional points, making it now have 35.0 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 75.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 8.5 points!!! 
smarty               chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 31.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 2!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 75.0 points, 
random better        with 35.0 points, and
smarty               with 31.5 points!!! 



Round #10 Reports: 

Bots Report: 
random better        chose 2 and got 2.0 additional points, making it now have 37.0 points!!! 
greedy better        chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 80.0 points!!! 
calculator           chose 1 and got 1.0 additional points, making it now have 9.5 points!!! 
smarty               chose 10 and got 5.0 additional points, making it now have 36.5 points!!! 

Distribution Report: 
The number of bots who chose 1 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 2 is: 1!!! 
The number of bots who chose 3 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 4 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 5 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 6 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 7 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 8 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 9 is: 0!!! 
The number of bots who chose 10 is: 2!!! 

Leaderboard Report: 

greedy better        with 80.0 points, 
random better        with 37.0 points, and
smarty               with 36.5 points!!! 



Final Report Card: 

greedy better       : 80.0 points. 
random better       : 37.0 points. 
smarty              : 36.5 points. 
calculator          : 9.5 points.
```

### If any bot runs into an error,

it fails. So **CHECK IT**!!! Make it **FOOLPROOF**!!!

### Winner

This is [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill).

Comment: I feel like you need a bit better explanation of how Greed Control scoring works, but otherwise, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Also, please reduce the number of exclamation points and bold chars in your post. IMO it makes it look childish and something like the stereotypical [plz send teh codez](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/114820/107299)

Comment: I'm childish... I'm 13... Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

## Cross of Numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a number `n` as input, output an ASCII cross composed of numbers counting up to that length. Counting starts at 0 in the center, and numbers with more than one digit simply have their digits printed in order in the correct direction.

Example for `n=12`:

```
               2
               1
               1
               1
               0
               1
               9
               8
               7
               6
               5
               4
               3
               2
               1
2111019876543210123456789101112
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
               6
               7
               8
               9
               1
               0
               1
               1
               1
               2
```

### Meta

Is this appropriate for [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)?

Answer (score 1):

## Categorising categories [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

A [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) is an abstract mathematical object whose actual meaning is not really important here. A category can be viewed as a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) with the following restrictions:

- every node in the graph has at least one edge from and to itself
- for every pair of edges which share an intermediate node (like \$ a \rightarrow b \$ and \$ b \rightarrow c \$), there must exist an edge which is their composition, like \$ a \rightarrow c \$

More mathematically, where \$ E(a, b) \$ means "there exists an edge from \$ a \$ to \$ b \$":
$$
\forall a \in G. E(a, a)
\\
\forall a, b, c \in G. E(a, b) \vee E(b, c) \implies E(a,c)
$$

Your task is to determine whether a given directed graph satisfies the above restrictions.

### I/O

You may take input using any reasonable representation of a graph, such as:

- an edge list
- an adjacency list
- an adjacency matrix
- a built-in directed graph type

You may assume there are no duplicate edges (but note that the edge \$ a \rightarrow b \$ is not the same as \$ b \rightarrow a \$)

Nodes will be represented by positive integers starting from \$ 1 \$, i.e., elements of the range \$ [1, n] \$, where \$ n \$ is the number of nodes. You may optionally also take \$ n \$ as a second input.

You should output one of two distinct values of your choosing, which correspond to true and false results.

### Rules

- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

## Meta

- Should I remove the first requirement ("every node in the graph has at least one edge from and to itself")? I think it doesn't add much to the challenge, but then it's less directly related to category theory <s>and I can't use the funny title</s>
- Is this clear enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: I know it's not really relevant to the challenge itself, but "A category can be viewed as a directed graph with the following restrictions:", this might be technically true, but it certainly is misleading.  It's sort of like saying that a group can be viewed as a set.  It's missing sort of the most important property.

Answer (score 1):

## [Solve the Zany car game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247552/solve-the-zany-car-game)

Comment: I think letting people choose input format may lead to more interesting solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## Bold Words for Profit

**The** **cha**llenge **is** **si**mple. **Gi**ven **a** **we**bpage **in** **h**tml, **ma**ke **the** **fi**rst **sy**llable **of** **ea**ch **wo**rd **bo**ld.

```
Example:

<body>Accessibility is a right, not a paid service.</body>

-->

<body><b>A</b>ccessibility <b>i</b>s <b>a</b> <b>ri</b>ght, 
<b>no</b>t <b>a</b> <b>pai</b>d <b>se</b>rvice.</body>
```

**We** **wi**ll **u**se **the** **heu**ristic **tha**t **the** **fi**rst **sy**llable **o**f **a** **wo**rd `w` **i**s **the** **pre**fix **o**f `w` **tha**t **goe**s **u**p **to** **a**nd **i**ncluding **the** **la**st **vo**wel ([**aeiouy**]). **I**f **the**re **a**re **no** **vo**wels, **bo**ld **the** **fi**rst **le**tter ([**a**-z]).

```
Examples (first syllable):

disability -> di
isnt -> is
for -> fo
profit -> pro
```

**You** **may** **bo**ld **te**xt **i**n **a**ny **way** **you** **see** **fi**t -- **the** `<b>` **ta**g **u**sed **a**bove **i**s **ju**st **fo**r **e**xample. **Whi**tespace **i**n **the** **ou**tput **H**TML **nee**d **no**t **be** **pre**served. **Si**nce **we** **wa**nt **to** **ma**ke **the** **mo**st **pro**fit **o**ff **o**f **thi**s **too**l **a**s **po**ssible, **a**nd **ea**ch **cha**racter **ty**ped **i**s **a** **hu**ndred **do**llars **pai**d **to** **ou**r **so**ftware **de**velopers, **the** **co**de **mu**st **be** **a**s **sho**rt **a**s **po**ssible.

**Ha**ppy **go**lfing!

[image: Bionic Reading]

Comment: It's worth taking into account that this technique is (unfortunately) patented by https://bionic-reading.com. I'm not sure what the legal implications of posting a question about it on StackExchange are, and I'd be especially worried about the implementations posted as answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Sell cinema tickets

Or in other words, print out a numbered grid from bottom-middle to top-middle.

## Challenge

Most people think that, in a cinema, the back seats and the middle ones are the best.
You'll be receiving the number of seats across and vertically in the theater, your job is to sell the tickets in prioritized order, starting from the best seats to the worst.
The seats will be numbered from top-left to bottom-right.

## Example

```
In: 3, 4

Seats:
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12

Out: 11, 12, 10, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1
```

The order of the outer seats doesn't matter, as long as the distance to the middle seat in the row is the same.

```
Another Possible output: 11, 10, 12, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1, 3
12: Priority 7
11: Priority 8
10: Priority 7
09: Priority 5
08: Priority 6
07: Priority 5
06: Priority 3
05: Priority 4
04: Priority 3
03: Priority 1
02: Priority 2
01: Priority 1
```

## Rules

- The number of seats across and vertically (in any order) should be received as the input
- Output should be the seats numbered, sorted by their priority
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply

Answer (score 1):

## [Extract the contained powers of two!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248128/104836)

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading, because the output is a list of matches, not "how many" (which would be the length of the list).

Comment: I also suggest a test case which has a power of two as a subsequnce, but not a contiguous substring. e.g. `106` -> `[1]`, not `[1, 16]`. Also, can the output may be in any order?

Comment: Thanks!! I have added your suggested test case, and improved the title.

Answer (score 1):

## [But is it a pretty place?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248047)

Answer (score 1):

## [Two In One: Guess That Language - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248188/66833)

## [Two In One: Guess That Language - Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248189/66833)

Comment: I suggest restrictions on languages (what is a valid language and what are different languages) to be taken from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot) - this seems to be a nice and working consensus.

Comment: Done @pajonk ..

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 1):

## [Sort my Cups](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248333/92689)

Answer (score 1):

## Parse Specification Data Structure Diagrams

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Many protocol specifications illustrate the structure of data packets or file formats with ASCII tables.  This helps to visualize the layout of the data in memory, a file, or how bits are transmitted "on the wire".

For example RFC 1035 section 4.1.1 describes the header of a DNS query with the following diagram:

```
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

RFC-793 Tranmission Control Protocol contains the following diagram of a TCP packet header:

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                        Sequence Number                        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
| Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
|       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Options                    |    Padding    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                             data                              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

- Wouldn't it be useful if we could automate the parsing of data buffers into the various fields based on these diagrams?

## Challenge

Your job is to write code that can interpret these diagrams to parse a data buffer into the data fields.

- Inputs will be a multi-line ASCII string following the format shown above, either an array of lines or a single string with linefeeds, and a data packet as an array of bytes.
- The input diagram includes the two initial rows that number the bit offsets (note that zeros in the first row may or may not be present).
- Bytes are in Big Endian ("network") order
- Bit offsets are from MSb to LSb
- The number of bits per row will be a power of 2 and at least one octet (byte).  I.e. 8, 16, 32, 64.
- For this challenge a single field will not span bytes from one row to the next.
- Some cases will require multiple lines of input for a single row of bits to accommodate the field names.  Field names are concatenated from the data in the field column over multiple rows.  For example see the fourth row in the RFC-793 TCP packet header. Note when field name values butt up to the edge of the field, no space is inserted between the characters on consecutive rows, otherwise a single space is between the field name values on each row. See "Data Offset" vs. "ACK".
- A single bit position could take two characters as in the ASCII diagram for the TCP packet header, or three as in the DNS query header. I.e. `+-+` vs `+--+`
- Output can be in decimal or hexadecimal with a '0x' prefix.

## Example Input and Output

Example 1 - DNS Query Header

Input:

```java
String diagram = """
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
""";
byte [] data = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x84, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Output (in hexadecimal):

```
ID = 0x0
QR = 0x1
OpCode = 0x0
AA = 0x1
TC = 0x0
RD = 0x0
RA = 0x1
Z = 0x0
RCODE = 0x0
QDCOUNT = 0x0
ANCOUNT = 0x6
NSCOUNT = 0x0
ARCOUNT = 0x0
```

Example 2 - TCP Packet Header:

Input:

```java
String diagram = """
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                        Sequence Number                        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
| Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
|       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Options                    |    Padding    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                             data                              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
""";
byte [] data = { 0xc0, 0x01, 0xa4, 0x74,
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
                 0x60, 0x10, 0x00, 0x04,
                 0x39, 0x3a, 0x00, 0x00,
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
```

Output (in decimal):

```
Source Port = 49253
Destination Port = 42100
Sequence Number = 2
Acknowledgment Number = 1
Data Offset = 24
Reserved = 0
URG = 0
ACK = 1
PSH = 0
PST = 0
SYN = 0
FIN = 0
Window = 4
Checksum = 14650
Urgent Pointer = 0
Options = 0
Padding = 0
data = 16909060
```

Understanding the tables:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

The above table section indicates that the 'ID' field is composed of the first 16-bits of the data packet (Big Endian), The 'QR' field is the high bit of the next byte, 'OpCode' comes from the next four highest bits of the same byte containing 'QR', The lower three bits of that byte contain the single-bit values for 'AA', 'TC', and 'RD'. 'RA' is the highest bit of the next byte, followed by 3-bits for 'Z'.  The lower four bits of that byte hold the value for 'RCODE'.

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
| Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
|       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The above table has several fields whose field names could not fit within the table using only a single line for that row of bits.  There are nine fields in these 32 bits.  The upper four bits of the first byte is 'Data Offset', followed by six bits (the remaining four of the first byte, and the upper two bits of the next byte) for 'Reserved' (i.e. unused).  The lower six bits of the second byte are for the six one-bit fields 'URG', 'ACK', 'PSH', 'RST, 'SYN', and finally 'FIN'. 'Window' is a 16-bit value made from the following two bytes (Big Endian).

i.e. pseudo code to unpack the data values for the above line:

```java
Data_Offset = (data[0] & 0xf0) >> 4;
Reserved = ((data[0] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((data[1] & 0xc0) >> 6);
URG = (data[1] & 0x20) >> 5;
ACK = (data[1] & 0x10) >> 4;
PSH = (data[1] & 0x08) >> 3;
RST = (data[1] & 0x04) >> 2;
SYN = (data[1] & 0x02) >> 1;
FIN = data[1] & 0x01;
Window = (data[2] << 8) + data[3];
```

The field names themselves come from concatenating the characters within each "box". Where spaces are trimmed from both ends, and all other white space is collapsed to a single space. You may also use an underscore, a hyphen, or a dot ('_', '-', '.') instead of a space to separate words of a field name. You must use some separator between words, conversion to CamelCase or straight concatenation of words is not allowed.  You must not alter the case of the field names as it may be significant.

The output must be printed or in the form of a single string that clearly pairs the field names and values.  Consider readability for humans.  I.e. a list of field names, followed by a list of values is NOT acceptable as this is too inconvenient for a human to find the right value for each field.  You may use one field per line and '=' as I have shown above, a two column table, a text format similar to JSON, CSV, etc.. There must be distinct delimiters between the name and the value and between different field-value pairings, e.g. I used "=" and newlines.  If you use a space between field name and field value, you must not use a space between words in the field name unless they are quoted or otherwise escaped so the output is unambiguous.

Comment: Could you please add a worked out example (maybe a simpler one)? I'm not familiar with the structure of the tables and I don't quite get what's going on. Also, please specify a winning criteria ([tag:code-golf] I presume?) and consider relaxing I/O requirements (i.e. add "or any reasonable equivalent" that would include e.g. array of characters for input or binary for output).

Comment: @pajonk I've editing for clarity.  How is it now?

Comment: Yes, looks better now. What types of output are acceptable apart from the format you show? - I suggest anything that will unambiguously identify the names and values (including but not limited to: named list, names and values space/comma separated, two lists (one with names, second with values), dataframe with two columns)

Comment: @pajonk I've clarified the output requirements.

Answer (score 1):

### [Speed up, slowpoke!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248531/104836)

Comment: (No, Slowpoke will only speed up in Trick Room.)

Comment: How many bots will a game have? Speeding down others only makes one of other bots 10% slow than me. But speeding up myself makes all other bots 11% slow than me. So I see no reason to slow down others in current game specification.

Comment: @tsh not neccesarily. it means **by 1/10**, like, not by 1/10 of their frequency, I guess...?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Done! <filler, text>

Comment: The new controller script is [here](https://txtpad.cn/speedup), with more examples.

Comment: It can access a **list**, not dictionary, of all the bots in the games' functions + current scores + current turn frequency, including itself, represented as [bot_function, score_integer, frequency_float]. Additionally, it will receive itself, so it can differentiate himself from other bots. It can also access the round number (from 1 to 300). So, `arg1 = [[bot,score,turn_freq] for bot in bots]`, `arg2 = itself`, and **`arg3 = round number`** which you didn't mention.

Comment: That link ain't sending me anywhere; I just see a blank textbox. Otherwise, fixed!

Comment: @23TuringMachine [this link](https://bin.disroot.org/?4dfb3c09467bdc06#51xvQdvUeHTTEdiuDgsfaGrGyfh2aVJEFSouYGQwTxgT) should be better. The old link redirects to a Chinese website.

Comment: @23TuringMachine technically I prefer "NobodyNeedsNames" or NumberBasher but it probably doesn't matter anyhow.

Comment: I would add it to PyPI when nothing will change. Gotta go to sleep now o/

Comment: Thank you @23TuringMachine, and maybe you can @ me when you are done so I can know (without having to navigate here), thanks!!! I would some time run it and upload a pic of the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to shuffle the info list. One reason for yes is it takes time. One reason for no is that it allows multiple bots to attack one specific bot. @23TuringMachine

Comment: SLEEP TIME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yeah, it'd probably be wise to shuffle it. We've time, after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137020/discussion-between-nobody-needs-names-and-23turingmachine).

Comment: BTW, In case you didn't see it, [New Code](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61341686#61341686)

Comment: I think we are ready to post it...?

Comment: Perhaps! Let's give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

## Parenthetical names

Your challenge is to build a program that puts parentheses around the 'title' part of names. For example, `Sonic the Hedgehog` is converted to `Sonic (the Hedgehog)`.

#### Rules:

- Inputs will only contain words (alphabetical characters and spaces).
- Your program must be case insensitive.
- Leading and trailing `the`s are ignored.
- With two `the`s in a row, only the first is parenthesized.
- Nested `the`s mean nested parentheses.
- Remaining `the`s are skipped unless surrounded by spaces. For example, the `the` in `their` would not be parenthesized.

#### Test cases:

```
'the pig'               => 'the pig'
'pig the'               => 'pig the'
'pig hog'               => 'pig hog'
'pig the hog'           => 'pig (the hog)'
'the the pig'           => 'the the pig'
'pig the hog pig        => 'pig (the hog pig)'
'the pig the hog the'   => 'the pig (the hog the)'
'pig the hog the pig'   => 'pig (the hog (the pig))'
'the hog the pig'       => 'the hog (the pig)'
'pig the the hog'       => 'pig (the the hog)'
'hog their pig the hog' => 'hog their pig (the hog)'
```

Inspired by this xkcd comic: https://xkcd.com/2252/

This is `code-golf`, so least number of bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Am I winning at O-Tris?

O-Tris is a very, very, very simplified version of Tetris, which is defined as follows:

There is a grid of cells that is 6 cells wide and 7 cells tall, known as the Playfield. Cells in the Playfield can be either Active, Inactive, or Empty.

There is a construct called an O-piece, composed of 4 Active cells in a 2x2 arrangement. An O-piece will always exist somewhere in the Playfield, and two O-pieces cannot coexist.

There are three commands, Left, Right, and Idle. No other commands exist.

Gameplay is defined as follows:

The user inputs a series of commands at the start of the game, which are stored. The Playfield is then initialized with all Empty cells save for a single O-piece in the top center, as shown the diagram below, where `.` represents an Empty cell, `#` represents an Inactive cell, and `O` represents an Active cell:

```
..OO..
..OO..
......
......
......
......
......
```

Then, each command is processed one at a time. For each command, the following process occurs:

- The first step depends on which command is read;

  - If the command is Left, no cell to the immediate left of an Active cell is Inactive, and no cell in the leftmost column of the Playfield is Active, then the rightmost two Active cells will become Empty, and the two Empty cells to the immediate left of each Active cell will become Active. (This is analogous to the O-piece moving left unless obstructed)
  - If the command is Right, no cell to the immediate right of an Active cell is Inactive, and no cell in the rightmost column of the Playfield is Active, then the leftmost two Active cells will become Empty, and the two Empty cells to the immediate right of each Active cell will become Active. (This is analogous to the O-piece moving right unless obstructed)
  - If the command was Idle, move directly to the next step.
- Second step;

  - If the two cells immediately below each the bottommost Active cells are Empty and within the Playfield, those two Empty cells will become Active and the topmost Active cells will become Empty. (This is analogous to the O-piece moving down if unobstructed)
  - If not, the following subprocess occurs;

    - All Active cells will become Inactive.
    - Any rows of cells within the Playfield that are are composed of only Inactive cells will be reset to be all Empty cells, and every row above that row will be translated downward, leaving a row of Empty cells at the top of the grid. **(Meta: is this well stated?)**
    - The game will attempt to place a new O-piece in the top center of the Playfield, satisfying the requirement that an O-piece always exist. If any of the 4 cells is Inactive, this will fail, and the game will enter a Loss state, inform the player that they have lost, and halt. Otherwise, continue to the next step.
- Third step;

  - If there are any remaining commands, return to step one and continue by reading the next command.
  - If no commands remain, the game will enter a Win state, inform the player that they have won, and halt.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to take a series of commands and return whether they would Win or Lose at O-Tris. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Input

Take a nonempty series of distinct values representing either the Left, Right, or Idle commands in any reasonable format. Assume no extraneous input.

### Output

Output one of two distinct values represent either a Win state or a Loss state. No other output is required.

### Examples

Using `L` as Left, `R` as Right, and `I` as Idle, `1` to indicate a Win state, and `0` to indicate a Loss state.

```
input => output
L => 1
LLLLLLLLLLLLLL => 1
IIIIIIIIIII => 1
IIIIIIIIIIII => 0
IIIIIIIIIIIIILLL => 0
LLIIIIRRIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII => 1
LLIIIIRRIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII => 0
LLIIIIRRIIIILIIIRIIII => 1
LLIIIIRRIIIILIIIRIIIIR => 0
LLIIIIRRIIIILIIIRIIIRR => 1
LLIIIIRRIIIILIIIRIIIRRII => 0
LLIIIIRRIIIILIIIRIIIRRLLII => 1
```

**(Meta: more test cases probably, specifically one where lines are cleared with blocks above it and that clear saves the player from losing)**

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Meta

Should I provide more diagrams? If so, where?

Answer (score 1):

## [Gray coded gray code convertor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248809/101306) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

Comment: This is an interesting [tag:restricted-source] challenge, but I think the task of being Gray coder is not very interesting, because it's just a numeric formula. I wonder if you could change this into something more in the category of [tag:quine], [tag:self-validating], or more generally [tag:self-referential]? Or maybe just to output a constant string, where the challenge comes from somehow encoding that string under these restrictions?

Comment: I'd also suggest replacing the word "character" with "byte", because the "bits" of a character are not really a defined concept, without also defining a character encoding, in which case you probably care only about the bytes anyway.

Comment: Finally, could you specify whether the empty program, and a one-byte (or one-character) program, is considered "safe" or not? It's unlikely you'll find a language with a one-byte builtin command for Gray coding, but possible, and I think you should handle those edge cases nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your feedback. I wanted to make this challenge not too hard, so I chose just the simple formula and I think that a lot of languages can't compete already. I think it would be interesting to change it into program which validates if its input is gray coded, but it feels harder, so I am not sure if it shouldn't be maybe separate challenge?

Comment: Also I chose word "character", because I think it would otherwise make using encodings such as UTF-32 very hard to use, but I guess not many answers would use such encodings. So I would like to ask you if you have some other idea how to change the wording of it, but if you don't, then I guess I can change it to "byte".

Comment: Yes, you're right; I have now actually tried this task, and it is pretty hard to do anything at all in most languages, so it's fair enough to keep it simple. As for bytes and characters, I think almost all answers will use either plain ASCII, or a [SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS), especially the kind used for most golfing languages. My objection is that a "character" *doesn't have bits* unless some kind of encoding is specified, and since we score using bytes by default on this site, so every language definitely has [...contd]

Comment: [contd...] [some way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10145) of translating into bytes, it makes sense to just use bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Flatten from the inside out

Say we have a ragged list

```
[ 
  [1, 2],
  [3,
    [4, 5]
  ],
]
```

And we want to flatten it by a layer, decreasing its depth by 1. We could flatten it from the outside:

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Or, we could flatten it from the inside.

To do this, take all subarrays with maximal depth, and disperse each into its parent array. For example, with the array `[[1, 2],  [3, [4, 5]]]`, the `[4, 5]` has maximal depth, so the array becomes `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`.

Your challenge is to, given a list, flatten it from the inside by one level. The list will only contain nonnegative integers, and will not contain empty lists.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

```
[[1, 2], [3, [4, 5]]] -> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
[[6, 3, [1, 3, 4]], 4, [2, 3, 9, [5, 6]]] -> [[6, 3, 1, 3, 4], 4, [2, 3, 9, 5, 6]]
[[[3]], [4, [5]]] -> [[3], [4, 5]]
[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]] -> [[[[[[[1]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Truncate words in a sentence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248753)

Comment: The second test case appears to treat `dQw4w9WgXcQ` as one single word, but it has digits in it. Should your definition of "word" be changed to include this?

Comment: @pxeger Oops. Will fix

Comment: Is input always printable ASCII only?

Comment: @pxeger yes. (filler)

Answer (score 1):

## Push some numbers

Given a list of integers, apply the following rules to each element:

- If n is even, move it to the back.
- If n is odd, move it to the front.

Zero is considered even.
You may assume inputs are always non-negative.

## Test cases

```
[1,2,3] => [3, 1, 2]
[0,1,2] => [1,0,2]
(more test cases coming soon)
```

Shortest code wins!

Comment: why treat 0 like a special case?

Comment: @thejonymyster fixed

Comment: you don't need to specify that zero is even :P

Comment: Are the inputs always non-negative?

Comment: @pxeger yes, always

Comment: I assume input-lists can contain duplicated values and can be in any order (e.g. `[10,4,1,5,10,2,3,2,3]` would be a valid input - which I think results in `[3,3,5,1,10,4,10,2,2]`)?

Answer (score 1):

[pattern-matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [turn-my-swag-on](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-my-swag-on)

## Is This Loss?

Given two shapes `A` and `B` in ASCII-art, determine if `A` appears within `B`.

A shape `A` appears in shape `B` if there is a way to overlay shape `A` onto shape `B` without covering any spaces that `B` is not already covering.

### Rules

- Standard I/O, any reasonable format etc. etc.
- Input will only contain two symbols of your choosing (as well as newlines) and can be assumed to be padded out / without any padding if necessary.
- Neither shape will ever be empty.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

Shape `A` (will remain the same for the next few examples)

```
#       #
#       #  #

#  #    #
#  #    # ###
```

Shape(s) `B`

Truthy:

```
#       #
#       #  #

#  #    #
#  #    # ###
```

```
###
  #       #######
  #       #######
  ###############
  ####    #######
  ####    #####
```

```
### #  # #### ### ### ###
#   #  # #  #  #  #   #
#   #### #  #  #  #   ###
#   #  # #  #  #  #   #
### #  # #### ### ### ###
```

Falsy:

```
#
```

```
    #       #
 #  #       #

    #    #  #
### #    #  #
```

```
# #
# # #

# # #
# # # ###
```

```
# ####### #####
# ####### ## ##
###############
# ## #### #####
# ## #### #   #
```

```
### #    #  #
    #    #  #

 #  #       #
    #       #
```

#### Non Loss example, for testing purposes:

Shape `A`

```
####
```

Shapes `B`

Truthy:

```
# # # ###### # # #
```

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Falsy:

```
#
```

```
## ## 
 ### #
### # 
 # ###
# ### 
 ## ##
```

## Meta:

Should I define anything more rigorously or is this clear as day?

Answer (score 1):

## Goroawase Numeric Substitution

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[Goroawase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay#Goroawase) numeric substitution is a common form of Japanese wordplay where homophonous words are associated with a given series of numbers to associate a new meaning with that series. Your task is to take an input of a Japanese pronunciation and output a sequence of numbers from 1-10 which can be pronounced as the input in Japanese. For simplicity, only follow the table below.

#### Substitution Table

| Number | *Kun'yomi* readings | *On'yomi* readings | Transliterations from English readings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | maru, ma, wa | rei, re | ō/ou, zero, ze |
| 1 | hitotsu, hito, hi | ichi, i | wan |
| 2 | futatsu, fu, futa, ha | ni, ji, aru | tsu, tsū/tsuu, tū/tuu |
| 3 | mittsu, mi | san, sa, za | su, surī/surii |
| 4 | yon, yo, yottsu | shi | fō/fou, fā/faa, ho |
| 5 | itsutsu, itsu, i | go, ko | faibu, faivu |
| 6 | muttsu, mu | roku, ro, ri, ra | shikkusu |
| 7 | nana, nanatsu, na | shichi | sebun, sevun |
| 8 | yattsu, ya | hachi, ha, ba | eito |
| 9 | kokonotsu, ko | kyū/kyuu, ku | nain |
| 10 | tō/tou, to, ta | ju, ji | ten |

<sub>(taken from the above link)</sub>

### Rules

- Input and output can be in [any convenient format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447), but it should be possible to tell the difference between 1 0 and 10. You can choose to take input in hiragana/katakana.
- You can assume that the input will always be valid.
- For inputs that could have multiple possible outputs (such as i being 1 or 5), any is acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1):



Answer (score 1):

## Photosynthesis [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

[image: Nearly finished game]

### Flavor text

You, a algae spore, have recently evolved the ability to walk. However, 3 others have just done the same thing. Can you use this new ability to your advantage and conquer the Petri dish?

### Game rules

The game is played on a 15 by 15 grid with one bot starting in each corner. The goal of the game is to occupy more squares than your competitors.

Each turn, each tile can perform one of 3 moves:

- Stay (Example: `[2] [ ] -> [3] [ ]`) Do nothing but gain one `stack`
- Move (Example: `[2] [ ] -> [ ] [2]`) Move one space horizontally or vertically. Stack stays the same. Space must be unoccupied and no other tile must be moving or splitting to the destination.
- Split (Example: `[3] [ ] -> [1] [2]`) Move half of `stack` to a adjacent square. Space must be free and no other tile must be splitting or moving to the destination. If `stack` is odd the destination gets the extra half stack.

Game continues till all squares are owned or if `15 x 15 x 4` turns have passed.

At most 5 obstacles per corner will be randomly placed on the board. They will be symmetrically placed so the map looks identical from each bots perspective. They will never be placed along the edge. There might be less than 5 obstacles if multiple happen to spawn at the same position. Example:

[image: Blank game board]

### Tournament rules

In the tournament each pair of bots will play each-other at least twice. Exact format subject to change.

Every win gives you 3 ranking points, 2nd place gives you 2 ranking points, 3rd place 1 ranking point, and 4th 0 ranking points. The bot with the highest average ranking points wins. (Since by necessity some bots may play 1 game more or less than each other)

### Controller

Controller can be found here [(TBD)](https://codeberg.org/Mousetail/Photosynthesis/src/branch/master) Note: I intend to delete all the example bots except `expand_bot` and `move_expand_bot` before the challenge is posted.

#### Example bot:

```py
import data

def expand_downwards(grid: data.Grid) -> list[data.Action]:
    # Bot always starts at [0, 0] from it's own perspective
    actions = []
    for x, y in grid:
        if grid[x, y].owner == 0: # You are always player 0
            # If I can't split
            if grid[x, y].stack < 2 or grid[x, y+1].owner is not None:
                actions.append(
                    data.Action(action_type=data.ActionType.stay, source=(x,y))
                )
            else:
                # If we can split, split down
                actions.append(
                        data.Action(
                            action_type=data.ActionType.split,
                            source=cell,
                            destination=(x, y+1),
                        )
                )
               
    return actions
```

### Do's and dont's

**Please**

- Use a single top-level function. Makes it easier to automatically import bots.
- Function name must be `snake_case` and include the word `bot`
- Typehint your program. This allows me to automatically check if you are following some of the rules.

**Don't**

- Use randomness, though you can use a seeded RNG if you like
- Print anything
- Take a excessively long time on your turn. Polynominal time algorithms only please.
- Access the filesystem, networking, or any other side effects
- Keep state between games. Keeping state between round of the same game is allowed. Precomputing things for performance is also allowed.
- Submit a bot with no other purpose than to help/hurt one specific other bot
- Exploit the controller

Comment: Why would you disallow randomness? A lot of valid algorithms might use randomness. Also, half the fun in a koth game is submitting some dumb bot that makes all its decisions randomly.

Comment: I want to be able to run the simulation once and have a reasonable sample, not need to run it many times to account for randomness

Comment: The restriction on randomness is a little unreasonable but allowing a reproduceable seed is I guess a good compromise

Answer (score 1):

## [Bloons TD 6 Upgrade Paths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249343/bloons-td-6-upgrade-paths)

Comment: add tag [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]. Interesting idea, I quite enjoy the upgrade path system in this game :) especially when the abilities that lock eachother out make sense to be mutually exclusive, like the catapult vs the crossbow

Comment: @thejonymyster actually idk if that applies because the order is not fixed

Comment: that just makes it a set, which still counts imo. "output this set" would make sense as kc. if anything, though, [heres another challenge which does that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85666/print-all-alphanumeric-characters-plus-underscore)

Answer (score 1):

## [Erverse Hte Ifrst Wto Eltters fo Aech Owrd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249523)

Comment: Will all words in input contains at least two letters? Also, a testcase where some first two letters of words are equals should be helpful.

Comment: Suggested testcases: `(empty input) -> (empty output)`, `i ate a banana -> i tae a abnana`, `pptx is one of ooxml format -> pptx si noe fo ooxml ofrmat`.

Comment: @tsh `and that there will be no one-letter words`

Answer (score 1):

## [Get multi-dimensional indices in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249489/92689)

Answer (score 1):

## Find the best character arrangement

[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

You want to write your English essay. However, all characters on your keyboard broke other than the arrow keys and the enter key. You want to find out how to place the characters so you can write your essay with the least movement.

Formally, you have to assign to each character of  `` !"$%&'()+,-./0123456789:;<=?[]`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz⇦⇧ `` a unique integer coordinate, and minimize \$ d = \sum_{c_1 , c_2} {\text{freq}(c_1, c_2) \text{dist}(c_1, c_2)} \$, with \$\text{dist}\$ being the Manhattan destince between the position of the characters, and \$\text{freq}\$ being the frequency of the character pair, [which is described here](https://pastebin.com/Yw9FcLv2), with the frequency of each pair not detailed assumed \$0\$.

### Scoring

The winner is the code which could produce the best result in a minute on my computer, with the tie breaker being the time until that result is found.

### Rules

- Your language must have a freely available interpreter/compiler capable of running on Linux
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed, except optimizing for the given test cases - you are allowed (and even expected) to fine-tune your solution to produce the best solution on this given test case.
- You can't hardcode calculations - the solution should be found by the code during its execution, not beforehand.
- You can use any reasonable output format (i.e. output your solution and when did you find it when your program terminates, output your solution whenever the program improves it, etc.).
- You will receive the frequency JSON in stdin.
- Your solution must be deterministic. You can use PRGNs, you just have to hard code their seed.

Answer (score 1):

## Where does the seesaw balance? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There have been a couple seesaw balance questions but none of them are doing this version of the question. [Adding weight to one side](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99545/add-weight-to-one-side-of-a-see-saw-to-balance-it), or [small inputs with ascii art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54311/balance-a-set-of-weights-on-a-seesaw) have been done already, but I think this would be unique enough to not be a duplicate.

**Problem**: Given some ordered sequence of single-digit positive integers representing weights (say 0kg to 9kg), output at what index or indices the fulcrum have to be at such that the beam balances. If it doesn't balance anywhere, then output some non-location without erroring.

This is assuming a massless beam. The fulcrum is at the center of one of the weights, and the output must be integer-valued (no putting the fulcrum between two weights). Output can be either 0-indexed or 1-indexed and should be specified in the answer.

Valid outputs if the seesaw balances would include `2`, `8.0`, `[5]`, a list of all positions that work, `"3"` and so on, but not `4.25`. Valid outputs if the seesaw does *not* balance anywhere would include `-1`, `[]`, `""`, `NaN` and so on, but not `0` or `[7]`.

**Example**: Given the input `[2,3,0,0,5,9,4]` the output should be `4` since a pivot at that index causes the torques/moments to balance (2*4+3*3+0*2+0*1 = 9*1+4*2). Below is a visualization:

```
2300594 (weights)
=======
    ^
0123456 (indices)
```

The weight at the fulcrum doesn't contribute to either side.

**Failure example**: Given the input `[1,3,4,1,2]` the output should be `-1` (or `null` or `[]` or some other obviously non-position output) because at no fulcrum position would this this seesaw be stable and balanced.

**Edge cases**: An input that is all zeros (eg. `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`) can balance at any index, but the program only needs to output at least one of them. An input that doesn't follow the input rules (eg. `[]`, `["a","b"]`, `[-3]`, `[1.234,2.34,3.4]`) is not expected to give any output of any kind and can error out.

**Test cases**: Using `NaN` as the "no solution" output. Output is 0-indexed.

```
[6] -> 0
[1,0] -> 0
[1,1] -> NaN
[9,1,9] -> 1
[1,2,3,4] -> 2
[1,2,3,4,5] -> NaN
[1,3,4,1,2] -> NaN
[2,3,0,0,5,9,4] -> 4
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> 4
[0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3] -> 5
[0,0,0,3,0,0,3,0] -> NaN
[1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] -> 2
[6,2,6,3,4,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] -> 5
```

Being code golf, fewer bytes of code is better here!

Comment: You might mention that we can use 0 or 1 indexing (if it is allowed)

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: Can we instead output all indices that would work (hence an empty list in the case of none)?

Comment: I don't see why not. In most cases that'll just be a list with one element but it covers the edge cases pretty well. I already had `[5]` and `[]` as valid outputs for the success/fail states but I'll clarify further.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC and thanks for using the Sandbox! I suggest stating explicitly that this is [tag:code-golf] in the challenge body (besides the tag).

Comment: Thank you! Updated

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151318/can-this-list-be-balanced Closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132512/where-does-the-pivot-belong

Comment: The second one might be close enough to be considered a duplicate, given that the main task is the same and only the input format is different. However personally I prefer the simpler format from this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Nest some addition, differently

This question is a follow-up to [Nest some addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249194).

Lambda calculus is a system of computation based on single-argument functions; everything in it is such a function. Due to this functional nature, juxtaposition is commonly used to denote function application, grouped from left to right. For example, \$(f g) h=f g h\$ denotes what would conventionally be written \$(f(g))(h)=f(g)(h)\$.

[Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) are a way of encoding the nonnegative integers in this system. They can be defined as follows: 
\$\begin{align*}
\overparen{\underparen0} f &= \operatorname{id}\\
\overparen{\underparen 1} f &= f\circ\left(\overparen{\underparen 0} f\right)=f\\
\overparen{\underparen 2} f &= f\circ\left(\overparen{\underparen 1} f\right)=f\circ f\\
\vdots\\
\overparen{\underparen n} f &= f\circ\left(\overparen{\underparen{n-1}} f\right)\\
&=\underbrace{f\circ\cdots\circ f}_n,
\end{align*}\$ 
where \$\circ\$ denotes function composition. In other words, the Church numeral \$\overparen{\underparen n}\$ can be seen as a unary operator on a function \$f\$ that nests that function \$n\$ times.

There is a another binary operator that performs addition on two Church numerals: 
\$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen a} \overparen{\underparen b} f&= \overparen{\underparen{a+b}} f\\
&= \left(\overparen{\underparen b} f\right)\circ\left(\overparen{\underparen a} f\right).
\end{align*}\$ 
That is, we nest \$f\$ \$a\$ times, then another \$b\$ times.

As with \$\operatorname{add}\$, \$\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen a}\$ is a unary operator that, when applied to another Church numeral \$\overparen{\underparen b}\$, results in \$\overparen{\underparen{a+b}}\$. Now what happens when we reverse the order, i.e. attempt to evaluate \$\overparen{\underparen a}\operatorname{dda}\$? This resulting function still has arity \$a+1\$.

### Task

Given (optionally) an integer \$a\ge0\$, and another \$a+1\$ integers \$x_0,x_1,...,x_a\ge0\$ in a consistent ordering, compute the integer \$n\$ such that \$\overparen{\underparen n}=\overparen{\underparen a} \operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{x_0}} \overparen{\underparen{x_1}}...\overparen{\underparen{x_a}}\$.

You will also need to know the multiplication and exponentiation rules: 
\$\begin{align*}
\overparen{\underparen{a\times b}} f&=\overparen{\underparen b} \left(\overparen{\underparen a} f\right)=\left(\overparen{\underparen b}\circ\overparen{\underparen a}\right)f\\
\overparen{\underparen{a^b}} f &= \overparen{\underparen b} \overparen{\underparen a} f.
\end{align*}\$

#### Example

Take \$4 \operatorname{dda} 3\,2\,1\,3\,2\$: 
\$\begin{align*}
\overparen{\underparen{4}} \operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}} \overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}} &= \left(\operatorname{dda}\circ\operatorname{dda}\circ\operatorname{dda}\circ\operatorname{dda}\right) \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}} \overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\\
&=\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right)\right)\right) \overparen{\underparen{2}} \overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\\
&=\overparen{\underparen{2}} \overparen{\underparen{1}} \left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right)\right) \overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right) \overparen{\underparen{2}}\\
&=\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right)\right) \overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\\
&=\left(\overparen{\underparen{1}} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right) \left(\operatorname{dda}\left(\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}}\right) \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\right)\\
&=\overparen{\underparen{3}} \left(\left(\overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\right)\circ\left(\operatorname{dda} \overparen{\underparen{3}} \overparen{\underparen{2}}\right)\right)\\
&=\overparen{\underparen{3}} \left(\overparen{\underparen{8}} \times \overparen{\underparen{5}}\right)\\
&= \left(\overparen{\underparen{40^3}}\right)=\overparen{\underparen{64000}}
\end{align*}\$

#### Test cases

```
a   x           result
0   9               9
1   2,2             4
2   3,4,5           5000
2   7,1,8           120
3   2,2,2,2         65536
3   2,3,2,4         7213895789838336
4   3,2,1,3,2       64000
4   3,1,4,1,5       8782696764280
5   1,2,1,2,1,2     42
5   1,2,1,3,1,4     176820
5   2,1,2,1,2,1     446941881
6   1,2,1,2,1,2,1   331776

5   2,2,2,1,1,1     46067585792061179986003103589270890479268003416963782070185329396818296983805445959073166440720581387038540029877988577743446452288030374115737071650858255804704645216460811594784946208110262803842901974222092931885696117997589640107161975226690021967819064275487285233512229404788315869062112469518816261355388074282508579612820589720868169439536003406995417291950455148984482997260637332557020455012974915559243748189682760671362747474046184227448861411296966290899881082905099904256926315617201402705453906211612138979485925239261758925413761498970666786937460520926437582982463058742990808351770234630680221463616795434886004399826242096099
```

## Notes

- I expect this should differ quite a bit from the previous challenge for non-lambda-calculus-based languages due to how \$a\ge4\$ expands.

  - But is there a viable method that's not just brute force lambda calculus expansion?

Answer (score 1):

## [Convert Descriptive Notation to Algebraic Notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249889/convert-descriptive-notation-to-algebraic-notation)

Answer (score 1):

[pattern-matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Find all matches for the digit pattern

In [an older challenge,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128252/does-it-match-the-digit-pattern) you were tasked with finding numbers which, in base-ten, matched this specific digit pattern:

```
(n)(x)(n+1)(x)(n+2)(x)(n+3) etc...
```

Meaning any number between 4 and 18 digits long such that the digits could be considered as a string of increasing single digits interlaced with (at most) a constant single digit number.

For example, `19293949` would fit the pattern, with `n` being `1` and `x` being `9`.

In this challenge, instead of deciding whether a given number fits one fixed pattern, you will be given a pattern as input, and are tasked with outputting the sequence of numbers which match the pattern.

### Patterns

This section is a definition of what the patterns are and what they represent. A format similar to the one used in the original post will be used for these examples. More clarification on I/O rules will come afterward.

A pattern consists of one or more clearly delimited tokens, each matching a single base-ten digit.

```
(token)(token)(token)
```

Tokens can either be constants, accumulators, or a loop.

Constants are each marked with a single token, and there can be up to ten different constants, as each distinct constant represents a distinct digit from each other constant. Here it is represented as a single character from `a` to `j` in parenthesis `()`

```
(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)(j)
```

This pattern, for example, could match the number `1234567890`, but not the number `1111111111`.

**Important note:** Numbers **cannot** have leading 0s, so the pattern would not match `0123456789`.

```
(a)(a)(a)
```

This pattern would match `111`, `222`, etc. all the way up to `999`. It would not match `000`, as it contains leading 0s, and it would not match `123`, as all of the digits marked with the same constant must be the same.

Accumulators are marked with a single fixed symbol. The first instance of an accumulator represents any digit from 0 to 9, and each successive instance represents a digit that is one more than the previous instance. Here it is represented as `(n+)`

```
(n+)(n+)(n+)(n+)(n+)
```

For example, this pattern matches `12345`, `23456`, `34567`, `45678`, and `56789`.
Combining constants and accumulators is allowed, giving us access to patterns similar to that of the original challenge:

```
(a)(n+)(a)(n+)(b)(n+)(b)
```

Constants can't match the same digits as other constants, but they *are* allowed to match the same digits as accumulators. This pattern matches, for example, `9192838`, but it also matches `1112333`.

This isn't enough to support the pattern given in the original problem, so finally we introduce the loop token. This token can only appear at the end of the pattern, or not at all. Here it is represented as `...`

```
(a)(b)(c)(n+)(n+)...
```

A pattern with the loop token matches all numbers that the pattern would if it did not have the loop, as well as all numbers matched by the pattern repeated twice, as well as three times, as well as four times etc. This pattern matches `78901`, but it also matches `7890178923`, as well as `789017892378945`, etc. all the way up to `7890178923789457896778989`.

```
(a)(a)(a)...
```

**Beware:** A pattern with no accumulators but having constants and a loop matches infinitely many numbers. This one matches `111`, `111111`, `111111111`, etc.

### Rules

Input can be given in any reasonable format, so long as each token type is clearly distinct, clearly delimited, and consistent. This includes lists of characters, lists of strings, lists of numbers, a single string, curried arguments, etc.

The loop token in particular can be taken anywhere in the input convenient, including separate from all of the other tokens. e.g. you could take it as a separate boolean input, or a command line argument, or at the beginning of the string instead, etc.

Standard [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply, so you can either output all matches, or take another number `n` as input and return the `n`th matching number, etc. Whatever the rules in the tag allow is fine with me.

You may assume any/all of the following:

- All patterns given have at least a single valid match.
- When given a pattern with finitely many matches,
  you will not be given an input asking you to exceed that amount of
  matches (so you wont be asked to generate the 11th number that
  matches `(a)`).
- Constant variable names first appear in some specific order. So you could, for example, accept `(a)(b)(c)(a)(c)` but ignore `(x)(y)(z)` and `(c)(b)(a)`. So long as at least one equivalent form is allowed, it's fine. I doubt this helps anyone, just covering my bases.
- Not strictly an assumption, but you are allowed to ignore `0` as an output number or assume no input will ask for it, as it technically breaks the "no leading zeros" rule. Edge cases wouldn't add much to the challenge :P

Finally, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

Examples will be given as a pattern, followed by a natural `n`, followed by the `n`th matching number (including `0`), 0 indexed, all delimited with `|`.

Still work in progress, the `?`s are temporary,

```
(a)          |   1 | 1
(a)          |   9 | 9
(a)(b)(c)    |   0 | 102
(a)(b)(c)    |   1 | 103
(a)(b)(c)    |   7 | 109
(a)(b)(c)    |   8 | 120
(a)(b)(c)    |   9 | 123
(a)(b)(c)    |   ? | 987
(a)(b)(c)... |   ? | 987
(a)(b)(c)... | ?+1 | 102102
(n+)         |   1 | 1
(n+)         |   9 | 9
(n+)...      |   1 | 1
(n+)...      |   9 | 9
(n+)...      |  10 | 12
(n+)...      |  11 | 23
(n+)...      |  17 | 89
(n+)...      |  18 | 123
(n+)...      |  19 | 234
(n+)...      |  24 | 789
(n+)...      |  25 | 1234
(n+)...      |  26 | 2345
```

## Meta

Should I allow leading zeroes in interest of reducing edge cases?

Comment: Can you take the loop as a separate boolean, instead of as a token at the end of the pattern?

Comment: @CommandMaster sure thing, i'll clarify

Comment: For examples format you can use just `pattern | beginning of sequence` or `pattern | n | nth number in sequence` (with several `n`s for each pattern). The second one may be better for sequences which are tricky for big `n`s.

Comment: @thejonymyster ofc you can use other delimiters like `\t` and justify to make it more human-readable.

Comment: @pajonk right thats a good idea, i was planning on justifying as well but i was rushed away from my computer ~_~; i feel bad about boosting this post to the top over and over so ill get it next edit when i add a bunch of test cases lol

Comment: Do the matches have to be in order? If so, do they have to be in numerical order, or can they be in lexographic order (like `10` being after `1`)?

Comment: @Steffan oh actually good point, i guess the order doesnt matter so much. that makes writing examples much more difficult though >_< will have to rephrase the rules next edit, ty

Answer (score 1):

## Runs Between Values

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In my work, I needed to find all the indices of values in a list that were between two given values. However, because these associated values tended to come in "clumps", it made sense to compress them into "runs", which describe sections of the list matching the criteria based on the starting and ending index of the sequence of matching values. For example, suppose we're looking for values between \$1\$ and \$3\$ in the following list:

```
i =  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
a = [1 4 5 3 2 1 0 5 2 3]
     ✓     ✓ ✓ ✓     ✓ ✓
i =  0     3 4 5     8 9
```

So we output \$[(0,0), (3,5), (8,9)]\$.

More formally: Given a list of integers \$[a_1, ...a_n]\$ and two integers \$x\$ and \$y\$, output all tuples of indices \$(i,j)\$ where the values in the subsequence \$[a_i,...,a_j]\$ are between \$x\$ and \$y\$ inclusive. (The values in the subsequence do not have to be in order.) You must return as few tuples as necessary to cover all the values between \$x\$ and \$y\$ - e.g. in the above example you should not return \$[(0,0), (3,4), (5,5), (8,9)]\$.

Your indices may start from 0 or 1. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

[Here's a program to generate test cases.](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ya6m5xde)

### Sandbox Questions

I haven't gone through all previous challenges, so I don't know if this has been done before.

Comment: I don't think the part of `x <= a_i <= y` is necessary for the challenge - I believe it would be better if the input was an array of true/false (and you only need to compress runs of true). It currently seems like you combine finding elements between x and y and compressing runs, which is generally [discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384)

Comment: Should I make a new challenge for that, or edit this one?

Comment: Since it's in the sandbox, it's fine to edit it however you want

Answer (score 1):

## [Next Special String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250139/next-special-string)

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "so you need to have some fast enough solution too". You might want to use [tag:restricted-time]. You should also [format the test cases to be easier to copy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101)

Comment: Is there any particular reason "just to make it even more interesting" is in LaTeX?

Comment: @CommandMaster Done, Thank you. 
No, nothing in particular

Comment: 30 seconds isn't objective enough, you should specify where it is run. [TIO](https://tio.run) might be good, or perhaps you just want [tag:restricted-complexity] (I'd say 30 seconds with \$ N \leq 300 \$ is approximately \$ O(n^{3.5}) \$)

Answer (score 1):

## Verify the diamond property

A polytope is a generalization of the concepts of polygons and polyhedra to higher dimensional space.

Now higher dimensional space is a little hard to picture so we have a variety of tools for thinking about and working with polytopes to ease this issue.

One of these tools is a Hasse diagram.<sup>1</sup>  The Hasse diagram doesn't preserve all information about the polytope, it is concerned with which *elements* of the polytope are *incident* on each other.

The *elements* of the polytope are the polytopes that make up the polytope, so for example in a polyhedron (3d) the elements are its *faces* (2d), *edges* (1d), *vertices (0d)*, the polyhedron itself, and the empty set<sup>2</sup>.

An element is incident on another if it is a subset of that element.  So for example, all the faces of a polyhedron are incident on the polyhedron itself.  No two faces are incident on each other even though they overlap at an edge.

There are a couple of properties we can observe.

- Every element must be incident on the polytope itself.
- The empty set is incident on every other element.
- Every element is incident on itself.
- Elements are only incident on other elements which are of higher dimension.
- Incidence is transitive: If \$A\$ is incident on \$B\$ and \$B\$ is incident on \$C\$, then \$A\$ is incident on \$C\$.

A Hasse diagram draws the elements of the polytope as a graph; connecting incident elements.  However we leverage these facts above to simplify the graphs.  For one we organize the elements in rows by dimension.  All the vertices go in one row, all the edges go in another.  At the top we have the polytope itself, and at the bottom we have the empty set.  We don't draw connections from an element to itself. Since all elements are incident on themselves there is no point.  We also don't draw connections between elements whose dimensions differ by more than 1, since these connections can always be derived from the transitive property.

[image: Example image]

<sup>Taken from [wikimedia commons image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pyramid_abstract_polytope.svg) by David Eppstein and Steelpillow.  This image has been released into the public domain by its authors.</sup>

**TODO**

I started writing this challenge, and it turned out a lot more complex than I thought because I have to define what an abstract polytope is.  I don't have time right now for this and I will come back later.

---

<sup>1: Hasse diagrams are used for many things not just polytopes, but we are going to skip over that because here we are interested in polytopes.</sup>
<sup>2: Thinking of the empty set as an element can be a little bit weird, but it does make the math simpler so we do it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Cube calendar numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261182/cube-calendar-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

## Move n, out n

Your task is to write a code, where if you move `n` adjacent characters, the program has to output `n`.
The code has to work for all integer n's \$0 \le n < \text{code-size}\$
The winning-criteria is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Rules

- Code length has to be greater than `1`
- You can choose which substring to move for each n
- Code size is *not* measured by bytes (ofc), but by the number of characters

### Example Program

###### `abcd`

`abcd` -> `0`
`bcad` -> `1` (Move a)
`acdb` -> `2` (Move cd)
`bcda` -> `3` (Move bcd)

Comment: Do we get to choose which substring gets moved and whither, for each n? Or do we have to make it work for every possible move??

Comment: @pxeger right I'll make it clear

Comment: Could you detail what each program should output, supposing your code is `abcd`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Find The Average String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250675/107299)

Comment: Tag: [tag:edit-distance]

Comment: `string, ring` can also be `sring`. The only other possibility for Hello and Ho is `Heo`.

Comment: If there are multiple possibilities, can we output all of them? If so, can it contain duplicates? (I'm running a script for Seggan, Steffan to look for more possibilities - it's really slow.)

Comment: Ok, it took like 10 mins to run, but here's the full list: `['Seffan', 'Sefgan', 'Segfan', 'Stefgan', 'Stegfan', 'Steggan']`

Comment: @Steffan thanks

Comment: you can remove "I hand-made these, so some might be wrong" sicne I checked them with Vyxal lol

Comment: Why cannot I simply output the first input and do nothing? For example, for input `Seggan, Steffan`, `Seggan` have edit distance 0 to `Seggan` and 3 to `Steffan` which average is 1.5.

Comment: @tsh The rules state: "You may not output any of the inputs"

Comment: @Steffan So, for input `abc`, `abcd`, should I output `abce` so it have average 1 instead of `abc` which have average 0.5?

Comment: How do we define Levenshtein distance with multi-case input? Is the distance between `Ab` and `ab` 0 or 1? I suggest sticking to upper- or lower-case. Suggested test case with no common letters.

Comment: Will the outputs only contain characters in the inputs? This would simplify things a lot, and the current test cases imply that.

Comment: @tsh Probably, the intended output would be `abd` with average 1, but waitnig for clarification.

Comment: @pajonk there will be no inputs without common letters. Sure, I'll stick to lowercase

Comment: I would suggest changing `output a word with "lowest average distance" to two inputs` to `output a word with "lowest maximum distance" to two inputs` and allow output one of input as-is. It may solve the confuse output for `abc abcd`, and keeping  all current testcases valid. This will be different if two input have distance at least 4, for example `abcdef, af -> [abcf abdf abef acdf acef adef]` but not `abf acf adf aef abcdf abcef abdef acdef`.

Comment: Also, when we say the average number \$c\$ of two numbers \$a\$ and \$b\$. We actually find out a number \$c\$ so that \$\max\left\{ \left| a-c \right|, \left| b-c \right| \right\}\$ is minimized instead of \$ \left|a-c \right|+ \left| b-c \right| \$.

Comment: From current specification, average of `aaa` and `aaaa` is... `aa, aaaaa`? it could be confuse to me.

Comment: @tsh allowing output of the input would just mean that for a lot of words you could just return the input

Comment: @Seggan No, if you chose "lowest maximum distance", the input will simply not satisfy the requirement. For example, For input `ab abcd`, `abc` has maximum distance 1 while `ab` or `abcd` have 2.

Comment: @tsh I misunderstood it as the lowest combined distance. Implemented.

Comment: Suggested test-cases: `abc,abcd`, `aaa,aaaa` (from above comments), `abc,abc` (or guarantee that the input strings are distinct), `test,longtestcase` (bigger Levenshtein distance between inputs).

Answer (score 1):

## Same number list shape?

Given two lists of positive integers, decide whether the two lists can be made equal by only repeated application of any/either of these two functions:

- Multiply all numbers of one list by a positive integer constant
- Add a positive integer constant to all numbers in one list

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

### Extra spec:

- You can assume lists will be at least three integers long.
- Both lists input will be the same length.
- Both lists will be given in strictly ascending order.
- Standard I/O and [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules apply.

### Worked out example:

```
list a: 2 4 8
list b: 1 4 10

multiply elements of list a by 3

list a: 6 12 24
list b: 1 4  10

multiply elements of list b by 2

list a: 6 12 24
list b: 2 8  20

add 4 to elements of list b

list a: 6 12 24
list b: 6 12 24

done, return truthy
```

### Shorter examples

```
1 1 1 1
3 3 3 3
true

5 10 11 14 16
2 12 14 20 24
true

10 100 1000 10000 100000
1  10  100  1000  10000
true

31   301  3001 30001 300001
1113 1131 1311 3111  21111
true

1 11 111 1111 11111
1 10 100 1000 10000
true

1 2 3 5 8  13
2 3 5 8 13 21
false

1 2 4 8 16
1 3 5 9 17
false

2 3 4 5
7 7 7 7
false
```

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Meta

- Is it a dupe of [are they colinear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206838/are-they-collinear)? Methinks maybe but this only has strictly ascending inputs, slope guaranteed to be on (0,inf) exclusive, and arbitrarily many "points".
- Better title? This was initially going to emphasize the fact that the allowed transforms don't alter the ratios of differences between numbers, but idk if it's relevant with this new phrasing
- Ascending order? Is this assumption necessary/would the challenge be better without it maybe?
- Any better falsy examples? I can't think of any other significant ones, probably will have to wait til post when people are all like "suggested test case:"

Comment: Another way to think about this is "do these 2D points lie on a straight line with positive slope?", where the lists contain the respective x- and y-coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implement String Projection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250781/implement-string-projection)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it's simply: keep characters from first input that are in the second input?

Comment: That's essentially what it outputs.

Comment: Why not state it in the challenge then? If you like, you may keep the formal definition, but I think it's just confusing. Also, what do you mean by `if you have unicode support`? Do we have to handle unicode or not? I suggest removing this test-case.

Comment: I like the challenge, but I think that adding an informal description of the procedure (like pajonk's) is necessary.

Comment: I suggest removing the formal definition of projection and the pseudocode. I don't think they help readers at all here.

Answer (score 1):

[Make a super fair number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265793/make-a-super-fair-number)

Comment: I'm not sure if the super fair condition is equivalent to every slice with an arithmetic progression of digit positions being evenly distributed, but I think this alternate condition might be easier for solvers to prove correctness for.

Answer (score 1):

## Longest N-Sum Sub-Array [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) [subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Write a program or function which when given an array of non-negative integers and a number \$N\$, output the longest contiguous sub-array whose sum of elements adds up to \$N\$:

$$S = \{ (x, y) : \sum_{n=x}^{y} a_n = N \}$$

$$\text{Output: } argmax_S (y - x)$$

### Constraints

- If there are multiple solutions, output any of them or all of them (choose one).
- You may output the solution in any reasonable format, which must allow for the following point.
- There will always be a solution, but it can be the empty list.
- \$N \ge 0\$.

### Test cases

```
[input array], N -> [output array]

[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 1 -> [0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 0 -> [0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0 -> []
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5 -> [2, 3]
[4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 5, 2], 8 -> [1, 0, 5, 2]
[0], 0 -> [0]
[], 0 -> []
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231557/longest-zero-sum-sub-array), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256556/find-the-first-run-of-numbers-summing-to-n)

Answer (score 1):

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

## When to give up and start again

Consider the following setup.  An evil wizard has ten opaque boxes in front of him. Hidden from you, he chooses a random number of coins \$x \in \{1 \dots 10\}\$ and spreads them uniformly at random in the boxes.  That is, there should be equal probability of assignment of coins to boxes from all possible assignments of \$x\$ coins to 10 boxes.  If you can prove that in fact there are \$x=10\$ coins hidden in the boxes the wizard will grant you a wish.

In this game, you can look inside one box at a time chosen by you.  When you do that, you can see how many coins there are in that box.

However the wizard, being evil, will never let you look in box 10.  This might still be ok as you might find 10 coins in the other boxes and in fact the only way to be granted the wish is to have found all 10 coins in the first 9 boxes.

Unfortunately, the wizard does not let you play the game for free.  It costs you one dollar to look in box 1, two dollars to look in box two, four in box three, doubling each time up to 256 dollars for box 9. Remember, you can never look in box 10.

The wizard has one last twist for you. At any point, you can choose to give up on this set of boxes and get him to start the whole process again (with a new random \$x\$). Of course, if you have looked in all the 9 boxes and you still have not found 10 coins you have no choice but to give up and start again. But you might want to give up earlier too. Sadly you never get any money back so your costs just carry on building.

Your goal is to devise a strategy that will get you the wish at the minimum expected cost. You should report your mean cost.

## Testing

Once you have chosen your strategy, you should run it until you get the wish 10,000 times and report the mean cost. If two answers have the same strategy, the one posted first wins. If two strategies have similar mean costs you may need to test it 100,000 or even more times to tell the difference.

Comment: "You want to find out if there are 10 points that have been chosen". I'm confused about the meaning of this sentance

Comment: @mousetail I meant if x=10. I'll rephrase. Thanks

Comment: What does "spreads them *uniformly* at random in the boxes" mean? "Spreads them uniformly" sounds like each box gets the same number of coins, but that obviously can't be true. From the rest of the challenge, it seems like he puts the coins in the boxes at random, such that each box contains 0 or more coins and each coin is in one of the boxes. (Also, I'm not sure how the boxes can be sealed if the wizard is putting coins in them--does he magically teleport the coins? Why can't the boxes just be normal unsealed boxes?)

Comment: @DLosc Thank you. I changed sealed to opaque. I also changed the randomness wording. Is it better now?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this a KotH? Could you put tags at the top if you find any that are applicable?

Comment: @user Added the tag. From reading the guidance it seems code-challenge is right.

Comment: "so your costs just carry on building" Does that mean that when you open the first box of the second set, the cost is one greater than your position in the first set?  Or does it reset to 1, but add on the the total from the first set?

Comment: What's the winning criteria?  Shortest code?  Lowest average cost?  If the latter, a consistent number of runs needs to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

## Solve the Greek Computer Puzzle Toy

Posted live: [Solve the Greek Computer Puzzle Toy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251124/solve-the-greek-computer-puzzle-toy)

Answer (score 1):

## Find "Millionaire" score

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

I was looking through [the uploads of GAMES Magazine to archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Games+Publications%22), and in the first publication I found a challenge called ["Millionaire: a word-and-number prize competition"](https://ia804601.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/2/items/games-1-1977-september/games-1-1977-september_jp2.zip&file=games-1-1977-september_jp2/games-1-1977-september_0022.jp2&id=games-1-1977-september&scale=4&rotate=0).

In this game, each word is assigned a score in the following way:

1. Turn each letter in the word into a number: `A` becomes 1, `B` becomes 2, `C` becomes 3, and so on.
2. Multiply the numbers.

For example, the score for `BED` is \$2*5*4 = 40\$.

(In the competition, the goal was to find the word whose score is closest to a million, but that's not relevant here.)

### The challenge

Given a word (i.e. a sequence of uppercase letters) as an input, output its score.

### Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `A` | `1` |
| `Z` | `26` |
| `BED` | `40` |
| `CHAIR` | `3888` |
| `BOTTOM` | `2340000` |

## Questions

This challenge is probably not new -- please let me know what it's duplicating.
I could make the challenge something like "given a list of words, find the word whose score is closes to a million", but I think that's particularly uninteresting.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/add-up-the-letters-in-a-word), likely related enough to count as a duplicate. This one multiplies the letters, that one adds them. Although if it was me, I would close the other one as it requires you to error if there's special characters, and you have to handle both lowercase and uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

## Guess the Caesar cipher shift

[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

A *Caesar cipher* is a cipher which takes a message and an integer \$n\$ between 0 and 25 (inclusive). Each letter in the message is then "shifted over" in the alphabet by \$n\$ letters, wrapping around the beginning of the alphabet. For example, when \$n=1\$, `A` becomes `B`, `B` becomes `C`, and so on, up to `Z` which becomes `A`. (Uppercase/lowercase is kept the same and punctuation is ignored.)

### The challenge

Given a string which represents a message encoded using a Caesar cipher with some shift \$n \in [0,25]\$, output a guess for \$n\$. (You can decide whether punctuation is included or stripped ahead of time.)
For example, if you take the word `Happy code golfing!` and encode it using a Caesar cipher with a shift of 3, you get `Kdssb frgh jroilqj!`. So if your program takes in `Kdssb frgh jroilqj!`, it should output `3`.
Your solution should be deterministic -- e.g. no random number generators.

### Scoring

To find the score of your function, it should be tested on every paragraph in [Pride and Prejudice](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1342)<sup>1</sup> and every possible
shift value (from 0 to 25). [Here's a link to a text file with each paragraph on a single line](https://controlc.com/6c9ee36e0), [and here's an alternate version where the quote marks have been replaced with ASCII alternatives](https://controlc.com/4a7a5a80). There are 2074 paragraphs, so there are \$26*2074 = 53924\$ test inputs. Your score is equal to

$$s(b,p)=(1+\sqrt{b}) (1+\sqrt{p})-1$$
$$b = \text{number of bytes}$$
$$p = \text{proportion incorrect} = 1-\frac{\text{number of test inputs correct}}{53924}$$

so, for example, a 100 byte program that got 13481 tests correct (i.e. \$\frac34\$ of them incorrect) would have a score of \$(1+\sqrt{100})(1+\sqrt{\frac34})-1 = 15.5\$.

Your goal is to minimize your score.

**[Here's a link to some Python code, which can be run online, containing a test harness, along with a baseline program to which you can compare your answer.](https://replit.com/@AdamL1/Guess-Caesar-Shift?v=1)** In this case, I've opted to remove all punctuation before parsing each line. For reference, this function is 89 characters and gets 40144/53924 tests correct, so its score is  14.70850917.

### Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `Hs hr z sqtsg tmhudqrzkkx zbjmnvkdcfdc, sgzs z rhmfkd lzm hm onrrdrrhnm ne z fnnc enqstmd, ltrs ad hm vzms ne z vhed.` | `25` |
| `“Rk! brx duh d juhdw ghdo wrr dsw, brx nqrz, wr olnh shrsoh lq jhqhudo. Brx qhyhu vhh d idxow lq dqbergb. Doo wkh zruog duh jrrg dqg djuhhdeoh lq brxu hbhv. L qhyhu khdug brx vshdn loo ri d kxpdq ehlqj lq pb olih.”` | `3` |
| `“That is a question which Mr. Darcy only can answer.”` | `0` |
| `Vczqrsvky cffbvu ritycp, reu klievu rnrp. Yvi ivjzjkretv yru efk zealivu yvi nzky kyv xvekcvdre, reu yv nrj kyzebzex fw yvi nzky jfdv tfdgcrtvetp, nyve kylj rttfjkvu sp Dzjj Szexcvp,` | `17` |

---

<sup>1</sup>Chosen because it's the most popular book on Gutenberg at the time of writing.

## Questions

The scoring function seems like it could be gamed by writing a really short, really inaccurate function, so I'm thinking of adding a function which penalizes incorrect answers even harsher.

Comment: Every paragraph in a whole book? Man, that will be a pain to do lol

Comment: Suggested tags: [tag:test-battery], [tag:cipher], [tag:string]. Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241532/crack-the-caesar-cipher

Comment: Suggestion: make accuracy explicit (as correct guesses / total tests). Also maybe add a line that the goal is to minimise the score.

Comment: @pajonk Is this too similar to the related question?

Comment: @Adam, no, I don't think so. Although the concept of reversing Caesar is common to both of them, the [tag:test-battery] will surely make resulting approaches very different. I provided the link only for reference.

Comment: you might want to ban random generators since luck can affect score

Comment: The scoring functions seems to mean that any code that gets everything correct gets a score of 0 no matter how long it is. An empty program also scores 0 in a language where this is a valid program producing 0, say by exit code.

Comment: @xnor I've updated the function to resolve this, though it's not particularly elegant.

Comment: a 0 byte answer with 0 correct will have score 1, same as a 1 byte answer that get 100% correct, which means 0 byte basically wins

Answer (score 1):

## [Optimally pop all the bubbles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251519/optimally-pop-all-the-bubbles)

Answer (score 1):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251705/does-there-exist-a-synchronizing-word)

Answer (score 1):

## [Make a Brainfuck Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251499/107299)

Comment: @thejonymyster woops. fixed

Comment: It might be nicer to allow solvers to assume that the input doesn't contain anything besides `<>,.+-[]`?

Comment: @Adam true. I'll update it

Answer (score 1):

## Render a triangle in vulkan

[vulcan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulcan)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The [vulkan API](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/) is famous for requiring graphic engines to be very verbose (usually at least 1000 lines of code for a basic result). I am curious to see how far we can escape this trend.

### Task

Using vulkan and no other rendering API, have a triangle rendered to screen with a color pattern as seen in this image:
[image: vulkan triangle]
For rendering to screen, some extensions are needed. You should use the minimal number of extensions and layers necessary.

**Points** are counted as the number of bytes of the program file plus number of bytes of shader files if needed.

You can take whatever shortcuts you want as long as it runs on your machine. You should provide a screenshot of the result as a minimal kind of proof.

### Hints

- As a reference implementation you can check the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation). The code of `15_hello_triangle.cpp` is 34536 bytes, and it uses two shaders of 389 and 158 for a total of 35 083 bytes. The c++ code is contained in a single file but this is far to be an optimal solution.
- You can assert the running machine will be yours and skip all the property checks for devices, queues etc.
- Well known window creation libraries such as [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) or SDL are authorized.
- You can use existing [Language bindings](https://www.vulkan.org/tools#language-bindings) to provide a solution in you favorite language.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and thanks for using the Sandbox!

Answer (score 1):

## [Calculate Pi unto a Point using the Nilakantha series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251919/calculate-pi-unto-a-point-using-the-nilakantha-series)

Comment: What should be the desired precision - are floating-point errors ok? Suggested tag: [tag:sequence] (+adopting output rules from there). Suggestion: merge odd and even cases to one using \$(-1)^n\$ for \$n>1\$. Please make the test-cases copy-friendly (see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/55372).

Comment: There you go. I've added all of that.

Answer (score 1):

## Calculating Pi using the Gregory-Leibniz series unto a point

Comment: Why can't we treat \$\pi_n\$ as a [tag:sequence]? Also, some test-cases would be nice.

Comment: I think this might be too similar to your earlier challenge on Nilakantha series. For instance, [loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251927/20260) is already summing up the Gregory-Leibniz series then correcting it by \$\pm 1/n \$ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Title

God Save the Queen (or King)!

## Input

A calendar year from 927 to the present year. For example 2022.

## Output

You can use any three distinguishable outputs.  As an example,

“K” (short for King)

or

“Q” (short for Queen)

depending on which was right in England in that year.  If there was both a King and Queen in that year you can output either.

If there was no King or Queen for the whole of that year, your code must output something that is not one of those two messages.

## Dates

Kings: 937-1553, 1603-1649, 1660-1702, 1714-1837, 1901-1952, 2022

Queens: 1553-1603, 1689-1694, 1702-1714, 1837-1901, 1952-2022

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: An interesting idea: instead of forcing it to be on January 1, allow years with multiple monarchs to choose one arbitrarily? Could add some depth to the compression strategies.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Good idea

Comment: Two downvotes?? Please explain

Comment: The fixed output strings are a common [thing to avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260). I think they'd be better off as any two outputs of the golfer's choice, with everything else corresponding to neither king nor queen.

Comment: @xnor that's a shame as the messages are what make the challenge more fun.

Comment: I really don't see how "K" or "Q" (which is what the output requires now) makes the challenge more fun.

Comment: @user it was previously "God Save the King" but I changed it on xnor's advice.

Answer (score 1):

## Is there a area that can see the entire perimeter of a polygon [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Oh no, your despotic regime has too many political prisoners and not enough guards! Time for drastic measures: Only build prisons that require only a single guard. But there are many prison design and little time. How to check?

### The challenge

Given a polygon, as a list of points, determine if there is a area (where the guard can stand) that can see the entire perimeter of the polygon.

Any convex shape trivially qualifies:

[image: pentagon]

Some concave shapes qualify too:

[image: concave shape]

But not all:

[image: concave shape where there is no place for a guard]

### Algorithm hint

The area where a guard can stand is the intersection of the areas on the inside of the tangent of every edge.

### Test Cases

| Image | Points | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | TBD |  |

Answer (score 1):

[Create a nibble shorthand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252258/create-a-nibble-shorthand)

Comment: Is it strict [tag:graphical-output] or we may return a collection of symbols (read: [tag:ascii-art]) to represent a nibble? Also, is scaling allowed (I mean, like mirrored `r` is smaller version of the image for the reverse of `r`)?

Comment: @pajonk It's graphical output.  Scaling is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## Construct Digit From Digits

In the game [All Ten](https://beastacademy.com/all-ten), each day you are given four single-digit positive integers, and have to use all four of those numbers once each to construct the values 1 through 10 using the following operations:

- Addition
- Subtraction
- Multiplication
- Division
- Concatenation, i.e. joining two numbers together; for example, \$1 \text{ concat } 23 = 123\$. (You can only apply this operation if both of the numbers are integers and the number on the right is non-negative.)

So, for example, given numbers \$[4,4,8,9]\$, to make \$4\$ you could do \$((4 \text{ concat } 4) - 8 ) / 9\$. which equals \$(44 - 8)/9 = 36 / 9 = 4\$.

You're allowed to compose these operations however you want, in whatever order, including concatenation (e.g. you can do \$16 - ((2-1) \text{ concat } 3) = 16 + (-1 \text{ concat } 3) = 16 - 13 = 3\$.)

### The challenge:

Your function is given two inputs: \$I\$, which is a list of four single digit positive integers (i.e. in the range \$1,2,\ldots,9\$) which are not necessarily unique, and \$n\$, which is also a single digit positive integer.

Your function should return a way of using all four numbers in \$I\$ to construct \$n\$ using the rules above.

#### Output Format

You can provide the output in any meaningful way, including:

- A string (or list of numbers/characters) representing the expression which evaluates to \$n\$, using any symbols besides \$1,2,\ldots,9\$ to represent the operations / parentheses necessary

  - e.g. `"((4c4)-8)/9"`
  - You're also allowed to represent concatenation with the empty string (i.e. no operator at all) -- e.g.  `"((44)-8)/9"`
  - You can leave out parentheses if you specify the order of operations -- e.g. you say that concatenation has highest priority, then return `"(44-8)/9"`
- A tree or nested list with where each leaf represents a number in \$I\$ and the parents represent the various operations

You may assume there is at least one solution; if there's more than one solution, you may output any of them.

### Test cases

[To do -- I need to enumerate *all* of the possible ways to construct a given value for this to be useful.]

## Questions

This is a really bad title, but it's hard to describe succintly.
There's also a lot of text here, but I don't know how to shorten it.

Comment: May the output be in Reverse Polish notation, removing the need for parenthesis completely? Or does that bend the 'provide output in any meaningful way' too much?

Comment: Also, is the division regular division or integer division? If the first, is something like `((1/5)concat 5)*8 = 2` valid (where `1 /5 -> 0.2 concat 5 -> 0.25 *8 -> 2`)? And how to deal with floating point inaccuracies in that case?

Comment: [Closely related - partial duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206195/represent-n-as-an-expression-containing-all-the-digits/) Difference is that that challenge asks to use the digits 0 through 9, instead of an input-list of 4 digits. And this challenge allows concatenation, whereas the other answer allowed exponentiation. [But my 05AB1E answer would be nearly the same.](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX//8WTIistLyrCqyIzw6PDsM60xaHOtC7OuUrLnC7OlC5WUf//WzQsNCw4LDldCjQ)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen (1) I think that Polish notation should be allowed. (2) It's supposed to be regular divison, though the expression you gave isn't valid because you aren't allowed to concatenate non-integers. I don't understand the second part -- the solver needs to handle floating point inaccuracies so they give the correct answer. (3) I don't know how close two challenges need to be before they are counted as distinct -- do you think this is still worth posting? It seems like the answer is no...

Comment: @97.100.97.109 In the original game, concatenation is only allowed on the original integers; i.e. you cannot do `(2 - 1) concat 3`. Is that not the case here?

Comment: @pigrammer You can if you do, e.g. `(2-1)=`, which saves a `1` to your "workspace", which means you can then do `1 concat 3`.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 No, it gives an error "Combo buttons cannot be used in two-digit numbers"

Comment: @prigrammer Whoops, I was wrong. I think I'll still allow it since it makes the application marginally simpler.

Answer (score 1):

### Prime number checksum

##### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253264/prime-number-checksum)

Answer (score 1):

## [Longest alternating subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/252692/78410)

Comment: If our language uses an SBCS, can we use UTF-8 if it helps with the score?

Comment: @Steffan You can choose the encoding in your favor if your language supports multiple encodings.

Answer (score 1):

## [A decimal-based unit of time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252942/a-decimal-based-unit-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

## Partition square into squares

Given integers \$n\$, \$m\$ and \$k\$, randomly output a list of \$k\$ numbers between \$1\$ and \$m\$ (inclusive) such that the sum of the squares of the numbers in the list is equal to \$n\$ squared. In other words, find a way to randomly split \$n^{2}\$ into \$k\$ squares between \$1\$ and \$m^{2}\$.

If there is no solution (which may happen if \$k = 2\$), you may exit from your program or return an error.

The program should take less than 40 seconds for inputs with \$k, n, m\$ less than 10000.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest score in bytes wins.

## Input

Three numbers \$n\$, \$m\$, and \$k\$.

## Output

A random list of \$k\$ numbers between \$1\$ and \$m\$, such that the sum of the squares of them is equal to \$n^{2}\$. All possible lists that satisfy the conditions should be equally likely.

## Test cases

```
Input (n, m, k)      Possible output
114, 100, 6          [13, 1, 25, 76, 44, 67]
114, 100, 6          [64, 58, 20, 32, 64, 4]
57, 40, 7            [2, 32, 18, 26, 26, 17, 16]
7, 10000, 2          [error]
7, 7, 3              [2,3,6], [2,6,3], [3,2,6], [3,6,2], [6,2,3], [6,3,2]
```

Comment: The time limit isn't bad, but it sure will make low efficiency languages unable to answer. Also, output all the possible result is better than randomly choose one, random is sometime unavailable and is hard to define, while adding no challenge to the original question. Nice question overall

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the Code Golf SE!

Answer (score 1):

## [Alphabet checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253568/114446)

Comment: This question may be tricky with our current default I/O rules, i.e. allowing I/O as char codes. Such I/O trivialises the problem (as it's just sum the input and take mod 26). OTOH, disallowing this explicitly may be disadvantageous to some languages that cannot process strings natively.

Comment: @pajonk - I'm going to say that the input must be a string. Otherwise, the challenge is way too easy.

Comment: Can we switch to uppercase if we want?

Comment: @Adám - I'll say no for that one. It needs to be lowercase. If you want, you can just convert it to uppercase at the start of your program.

Comment: Also, I forgot to link it but I've already posted the challenge on the main site.

Comment: Can we use 1-based alphanumeric mapping? With `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ... z = 26` instead of `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 ... z = 25`? Obviously, this changes the outputs...

Comment: @acvill - no. It must be 0-based. Also, the challenge has already been posted on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

## [Increment, decrement, undo, peek](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253817/increment-decrement-undo-peek)

Comment: Nice challenge! I was thinking maybe add the tags: [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) and [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: I think this is a very interesting challenge, but the definitions for the four functions are very difficult to understand as they're currently written. I haven't figured out a really good way to phrase them, but at the very least I think replacing "has the value" with something like "contains the value". When I read "Increment has the value of the function that created it plus 1" it took me a long time to figure out that it didn't mean `incr == 1`.

Comment: What should `eval(undo)()` return in your example? Maybe this is undefined and we don't need to handle such cases? Do we need to keep track of all operations for `undo` or there's a limit?

Comment: @pajonk Good questions, thanks. I suppose that behavior should just be undefined. Re: Limit I think the only limit should be the limitations of your system/language.

Answer (score 1):

### [Length of Binary as Base 10 [OEIS A242347]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253857/length-of-binary-as-base-10-oeis-a242347)

Comment: Can we use default [tag:sequence] rules and output infinitely, or output the first \$n\$ terms?

Comment: I'll edit it to output the first n terms

Comment: I second @Sʨɠɠan's suggestion to allow standard [tag:sequence] rules. Also, your wording now is misleading - A242347 **isn't** `the number of digits in the first n terms` of A008559 (it's the number of digits of the `n`th term). I suggest changing the tile to reflect the challenge by adding "Length of" and updating the OEIS number accordingly. Another thing, good practice is to give meaningful labels to hyperlinks - I suggest changing "here" to "A008559" and "this sequence" to "sequence A242347".

Comment: @pajonk will do

Comment: Your test cases don't match the specs currently (only one number instead of first n terms).  Also, the \$a(1)=2\$ in the Input section is confusing.

Comment: fixed those issues

Answer (score 1):

## Render an Ideographic Description Sequence

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

There are 12 characters in Unicode that can be used to describe any CJK character, which are often made up of reoccurring parts ("radicals") composed in different ways.

For example, U+86D9 蛙 can be described as U+2FF0 U+866B U+572D ⿰虫圭.

Your task is to take such an Ideographic Description Sequence as input and produce an image of the resulting character as an output. You can assume the input conforms to the following grammar, which is taken from [the Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/UnicodeStandard-15.0.pdf#G21.28626), which explains this topic very well:

```
IDS := Ideographic | Radical | CJK_Stroke | Private Use | U+FF1F
    | IDS_BinaryOperator IDS IDS
    | IDS_TrinaryOperator IDS IDS IDS
CJK_Stroke := U+31C0 | U+31C1 | ... | U+31E3
IDS_BinaryOperator := U+2FF0 | U+2FF1 | U+2FF4 | ... | U+2FFA | U+2FFB
IDS_TrinaryOperator := U+2FF2 | U+2FF3
```

This is a kind of prefix notation (polish notation).

*Ideographic* and *Radical* are defined in [PropList.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/ucd/PropList.txt):

```
2E80..2E99    ; Radical # So  [26] CJK RADICAL REPEAT..CJK RADICAL RAP
2E9B..2EF3    ; Radical # So  [89] CJK RADICAL CHOKE..CJK RADICAL C-SIMPLIFIED TURTLE
2F00..2FD5    ; Radical # So [214] KANGXI RADICAL ONE..KANGXI RADICAL FLUTE

3006          ; Ideographic # Lo       IDEOGRAPHIC CLOSING MARK
3007          ; Ideographic # Nl       IDEOGRAPHIC NUMBER ZERO
3021..3029    ; Ideographic # Nl   [9] HANGZHOU NUMERAL ONE..HANGZHOU NUMERAL NINE
3038..303A    ; Ideographic # Nl   [3] HANGZHOU NUMERAL TEN..HANGZHOU NUMERAL THIRTY
3400..4DBF    ; Ideographic # Lo [6592] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-3400..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4DBF
4E00..9FFF    ; Ideographic # Lo [20992] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E00..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-9FFF
F900..FA6D    ; Ideographic # Lo [366] CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-F900..CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FA6D
FA70..FAD9    ; Ideographic # Lo [106] CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FA70..CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FAD9
16FE4         ; Ideographic # Mn       KHITAN SMALL SCRIPT FILLER
17000..187F7  ; Ideographic # Lo [6136] TANGUT IDEOGRAPH-17000..TANGUT IDEOGRAPH-187F7
18800..18CD5  ; Ideographic # Lo [1238] TANGUT COMPONENT-001..KHITAN SMALL SCRIPT CHARACTER-18CD5
18D00..18D08  ; Ideographic # Lo   [9] TANGUT IDEOGRAPH-18D00..TANGUT IDEOGRAPH-18D08
1B170..1B2FB  ; Ideographic # Lo [396] NUSHU CHARACTER-1B170..NUSHU CHARACTER-1B2FB
20000..2A6DF  ; Ideographic # Lo [42720] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-20000..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2A6DF
2A700..2B739  ; Ideographic # Lo [4154] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2A700..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2B739
2B740..2B81D  ; Ideographic # Lo [222] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2B740..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2B81D
2B820..2CEA1  ; Ideographic # Lo [5762] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2B820..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2CEA1
2CEB0..2EBE0  ; Ideographic # Lo [7473] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2CEB0..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-2EBE0
2F800..2FA1D  ; Ideographic # Lo [542] CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-2F800..CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-2FA1D
30000..3134A  ; Ideographic # Lo [4939] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-30000..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-3134A
31350..323AF  ; Ideographic # Lo [4192] CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-31350..CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-323AF
```

### Rules

Keep in mind that output has to be an image, not a unicode character, as per the [default loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12155), but I recommend a text rendering engine to render each radical.

You can assume the input won't contain private use characters.

Use the following definitions of the Ideographic Description Characters. The percentages are not defined in unicode, but made up for this challenge. Each component should be squashed to the required shape, so that each intermediate result is a square. The output should also be a square image. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_languages#Ideographic_Description_Sequences

| Code point | Character | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U+2FF0 | ⿰ | divide horizontally in halves |
| U+2FF1 | ⿱ | divide vertically in halves |
| U+2FF2 | ⿲ | divide horizontally in thirds |
| U+2FF3 | ⿳ | divide vertically in thirds |
| U+2FF4 | ⿴ | enclose; the lengths should be 20%, 60%, 20% |
| U+2FF5 | ⿵ | surround from top; the inner has 60% the width and 80% of the height |
| U+2FF6 | ⿶ | surround from below; the inner has 60% the width and 80% of the height |
| U+2FF7 | ⿷ | surround from left; the inner has 80% the width and 60% of the height |
| U+2FF8 | ⿸ | surround from top-left; the inner has 80% the width and height |
| U+2FF9 | ⿹ | surround from top-right; the inner has 80% the width and height |
| U+2FFA | ⿺ | surround from top-right; the inner has 80% the width and height |
| U+2FFB | ⿻ | overlay with transparency |

### Examples

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 虫 | 虫 |
| 鬱 | 鬱 |
| ⿰虫圭 | 蛙 |
| ⿲彳圭亍 | 街 |
| ⿵几皇 | 凰 |
| ⿻工从 | 巫 |
| ⿴囗⿰⿱鹵凼⿰丨㇌ | [image: 2] |
| ⿱井蛙 | [image: 1] |
| ⿱井⿰虫圭 | [image: 1] |
| ⿱井⿰虫⿱土土 | [image: 1] |

Comment: Is it too long?

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain why?

Comment: why not restrict output to graphical ones only for simplicity?

Comment: @鳴神裁四点一号 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This is [tag:graphical-output], so the output must be an image or image file.

Answer (score 1):

## [Power sequence differences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253989/114446)

Comment: Any reason for the `first 5 terms` portion in the challenge description? I see in the rules you allow the default `[sequence]` rules, so it can be the \$n^{th}\$, first \$n\$, or infinite sequence, instead of specifically the first \$5\$, right?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I will edit the challenge to allow anything that includes the 5th term. This includes the first 5 terms, just the 5th term, or the infinite sequence.

Comment: These finite differences have a [closed form](https://tio.run/##HYvLDoIwEEX3/YoJqxkoREQTY6Jf4qbYIk3oI6UaDOHbsXU2Z3Luvf4bR2e7iw/7ro13IYIRcWTDbRKmlwIWLq/z22C2zdOZHiXXVOKpknViuZRYt4kaBhdAg7YQhH0plFVLtEc1xxlu4LyyeKAmKCGRmtlPOmLxsAUxloe5l7f//pVBOstlGqqPmDBb@ksftI04FGtKN6jvsA6YXtoK2k/8yI68ZV3imXc/), which I'm not sure is your intention? No matter what you choose you should define the domains of \$ x \$ and \$ d \$.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't get what you mean by that. Could you explain further?

Comment: For the first part of my comment, I wanted to let you know that the 5th term of the \$d\$th difference sequence of \$n^{x}\$ was \$ \sum_{i=0}^{d} \binom{d}{i} (4+d-i)^{x} (-1)^{x} \$. I think a lot of answers would probably use that rather than manually computing difference sequences, which I wasn't sure was what you wanted. There isn't anything wrong with it, unless you don't like it. The other part is that you don't specify that \$ x \$ and \$ d \$ are positive integers and \$ d < x \$. You can choose other domains, but those are true of your test cases.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - for the first bit, I don't really mind if people use a formula for it. For the second bit, yes that is the domain I wanted. I'll edit that in now.

Answer (score 1):

## Longest Total Distance Cyclic Quine Chain [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

Write a program of upto 100 bytes that outputs another program that outputs another program etc. until after a *finite* number of iterations outputting the original program again.

Each program in the cycle must have a length less than or equal to 100 bytes.

Your score is the sum of the Levenshtein distance between each program and it's output. I hope this leads to answers that do something more creative than change a single digit each time.

Maximum possible score is: $$256^{101}$$

Comment: finite? As in, how many iterations *exactly*?

Comment: Like after 10, 20, or 100?

Comment: The goal is to get the highest finite number of iterations

Comment: I imagine scores will be around 10^100

Comment: I see. And why upto 100 bytes? I imagine some really verbose language like Taxi wouldn't be able to answer this.

Comment: Related: [Cyclic levenquine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/116189/78410)

Comment: I need to set a limit or you could easily get arbitrarily high scores. Shorter languages can easily get scores that are so high as to be uncomputable even for short lengths. I hope with this length languages like python can participate but golfing languages can still genuinely compete against each-other, since their difference in score is hopefully representable.

Comment: And I don't really understand ` that outputs another program `. Are we supposed to output the source code of another program, that when executed output's the source code of yet another one?

Comment: @Bubbler It's different since you are trying to get the highest distance possible instead of a distance of exactly 1

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer yes, it's a quine like

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer Not being answerable in some languages is totally OK. @ mousetail: Yes, I'm aware of the differences.

Comment: Would some test cases in a particular... No, never mind.

Comment: 1) I think you should clarify that it is NOT "longest chain, ties broken by highest distance sum". I guess my initial misconception is due to the title. Maybe "Most distant cyclic quine chain"? 2) The theoretical maximum score is `(sum of lengths of all possible programs of 100 bytes or shorter) * 2`, which is a bit lower than `256^101`.

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:busy-beaver]

Answer (score 1):

## [Perfect Nontransitive Sets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254449/perfect-nontransitive-sets)

Comment: "in comparing two tuples the one that has more elements greater than _the other_ is greater" - how do we compare each element to the other tuple? Maybe you mean that we should compare elements to the _respective_ element in the other tuple (i.e. zip with `<`) and then the lesser tuple is the one with more truthy results? Or maybe you mean we compare an element to each of the three in the other tuple? Maybe a worked example would help.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Shoot, I was afraid the wording there was confusing. Yes, it's essentially zip with `<`, hopefully the the edits clear up my intent.

Comment: It seems that `{(n-i, 0, i) for i in range(n)}` will satisfy the property (since no pair of elements contain one that is less than the other).

Comment: ...e.g. `{(1, 0, 4), (2, 0, 3), (3, 0, 2), (4, 0, 1), (5, 0, 0)}`

Comment: @JonathanAllan This would not be a valid set since none of them are comparable. It appears things are still confusing. Do you think it would be better if I simply disallow tuples that have any element-wise equalities?

Comment: So "all pairs must be comparable" means one must be "less than" the other? If you spell that out it's probably fine, but it would probably be worth adding an invalid example output to ensure the point gets accross.

Comment: Went ahead and did both, if anybody still finds this confusing let me know

Answer (score 1):

## [Number to letters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254728/114446)

Answer (score 1):

## [Is it a legal atomic chess move?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254857/is-it-a-legal-atomic-chess-move)

Comment: How would one know what the move is? Make sure to include that in the input

Comment: @DialFrost errr I’m not too sure I understand… it is part of the input, that’s the entire point of the challenge.

Comment: You didnt state it in any part of the question!

Comment: @DialFrost I did… “….given a board state, whose turn it is (black or white), and **a move**….”

Comment: You didnt show it in the input examples you have :/ (NOT testcases)

Comment: @DialFrost Wait what, but those aren't even test cases... those are just example positions to explain the game rules. Those aren't actual inputs. I haven't even made any test cases yet.

Comment: Given that this challenge is already complicated enough, I suggest simplifying input to just cover white's turn (or black's, whatever).

Comment: @pajonk good idea, I will edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

## Print the most uncommon character

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential)

Your task is to write a full program or function that prints the character(s)* that appears in your code the least. For example, if my code was `AAAABBBBCCCDDD`, then the program should print `CD` or `DC`.

### Rules

- All printed characters must appear at least three times in your code, but you will print only one character for each.
- You are only printing those character(s). If your language always includes a trailing newline, then that is allowed.
- All printed characters must be printable characters or newlines.
- If multiple characters all appear the least, you must print them all, without separation. Order does not matter.
- The program or function cannot be empty, so it has to be a minimum of three characters long.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

<sub>*Where "character(s)" is mentioned in the rules above, exceptions may be made for languages like TI-Basic or Piet which do not use characters.</sub>

### Meta

- Are there any similar questions to this?
- Should I change the rules?

Comment: Can't find any challenges that are similar. And I think the rules itself are fine, but I personally find the `*` after every character a bit distracting. Maybe remove those five `*` and change the footnote to "_*Where 'character(s)' is mentioned in the rules above, exceptions may be made for languages like TI-Basic or Piet, which do not use characters._" And just to make sure: the shortest program is 3 bytes with three of one character, that outputs one of such character?

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you specifically said 'full program', as apposed to the default program/function? The default is there for languages with verbose boilerplate code like Java or .NET C#.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The shortest possible solution would indeed be 3 characters long. I found that a full program would fit better for a self-referential challenge, but I suppose a function would also be fine. I will replace the `*`s in the rules.

Comment: I think a lot of languages will have the solution `000`. Additionally, I think it isn't a great idea to say "character" as characters are things that we see, rather than the bytes that make up a program. For example, should the Jelly program `AAA` output `A` or `)`? Both are `0x41` (what appears in the program) but one is the ASCII code page and the other is the Jelly code page.

Answer (score 1):

## [`><>` numbers metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255297/numbers-metagolf)  [coding-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-challenge)[meta-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-golf)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

Comment: I suggest linking to TIO (https://tio.run/#fish) or other online interpreter in the section "you can test your programs..."

Answer (score 1):

## [Find the nth number where the digit sum equals the number of factors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254910/114446)

Comment: Tag: [tag:sequence]

Comment: Since this is [tag:sequence], can we use default sequence rules and output infinitely? Or return the first n numbers?

Comment: @Steffan yes you can. I've edited it into the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Range of ASCII values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254947/114446)

Answer (score 1):

## [Join Columnar Strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255070/join-columnar-strings)

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: "You may NOT assume inputs are ASCII only" seems like a _really_ bad rule. It heavily restricts the challenge for a ton of languages and adds absolutely nothing.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms edited to ascii only

Answer (score 1):

## [Smallest and largest 100-bit square with maximum Hamming weight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255529/smallest-and-largest-100-bit-square-with-maximum-hamming-weight)

Answer (score 1):

### Merged strings

Not sure if this is already done

Basically, take two strings of reasonable length (like <32 chars) of numbers and X's and find the shortest superposition of those strings such that there's no 2 numbers at the same position. Number+X or X+X is allowed. Print the result.

#### Examples:

```
["01XX02","10XX2"]
-----
010X02

["5234XXX","431XXX"]
-----
523431XXX
```

#### Note:

- Even if the string ends with X's, print those X's as they're part of the strings.
- Oh and the result must start with the first string. (like test 4)

#### Tests:

```
1234   | 345    -> 12345
6573   | 2625   -> 65732625
11X    | 12     -> 112
XX1XX  | XX2XX  -> XX12XX
X1X2X3 | 1XX234 -> X1X2234
```

### Scoring

The program with the least bytes wins!

Comment: In the current form this question is unclear. Please expand a bit and include test cases. Make sure to also include a scoring criteria

Comment: @mousetail Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

## KotH: Don't Kill the Curve!

In this KotH, you will take a test at school. Your goal, of course, is to get the highest grade, up to a maximum of 110%. This score consists of your actual grade, curved, as well as 10% which is the average of other students' scores, since your teacher wants to encourage students to study together.

You have a minimum of 100 turns leading up to the test. You can use these to either:

- Study: This add a point to your score (initially 0), unless your score is already 100
- Tutor: Adds two points to the score of any other student, up to a max of 100
- Arson: Majorly disrupt another student's life, dropping their score by 10 points (down to a minimum of zero), and negating their next 10 actions as they rebuild their life

Arson requires a lengthy jail sentence, meaning that your next 10 actions are also negated. If you have fewer than 10 actions left, you miss the test, and must retake it, making the maximum score you can receive (after the curve, before the bonus from other students) 70 points. Your real score is still used in the class average. Note that being an arson victim in the last 10 turns does not prevent you from taking the test; it only prevents you from studying, tutoring, or paying it forward.

You can also miss the test by taking more than 100 turns. After 100 turns you can only tutor or commit arson against other students which have not yet taken the test. Missing the test normally still has the same impact as if you had missed it while in jail, so it is likely only an effective strategy if you would otherwise receive a score below 70 (perhaps due to being an arson victim or avid tutor).

The test is also curved. Whichever student has the highest raw score will have theirs adjusted to 100, and that same shift will be applied to all other students. The curve is not taken into account for student averages, so if all students receive a 20% raw score, they would receive 102% as their final score (if they did not miss the test).

**Information:**

You are aware of all other students' scores on previous tests, your own "preparedness" (the raw score you would get if you took the test now), and the list of students who are recovering from arson and/or in jail.

Comment: The cooperative aspect seems like it's intended to be a major aspect, but since the average score will be applied to all bots there seems to be no benefit to helping others for the final ranking. Unlike a real test where absolute score matters.

Comment: @mousetail That's a good point. One thing I'm considering, not sure if this would fix the problem, is running different combinations of bots instead of all of them for every game. That way a bot that's really bad at collaborating would lose points for pretty much every game, while the others it's matched with would only lose points due to it on a few games, giving the bad bot a lower total amount of points.

Comment: Yes that might be better. You could even consider putting multiple copies of each bot in each classroom to increase the benefit of cooperation even more

Comment: @mousetail Ooh that's a good idea. Maybe even running a bot against itself only could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

## Two-leg train journey

Joseph wants to travel by train from town A to town C.  There is no direct train, so he wants to transfer in town B.  You get the railway timetables from A to B and from B to C, and the latest time when Joseph needs to arrive to C.  Compute the latest time that Joseph can arrive to the railway station in A and still be in time.

Times are given as integers between 0 and 1440, meaning the number of minutes from midnight on the day of the journey.  A schedule from a town to another is given as a list of pairs, each pair made of two times, namely the time when the train departs from the first station and the time when it arrives to the second station.  Your program gets three inputs: the train schedule from town A to town B, the train schedule from town B to town C, and the time when Joseph has to arrive to C the latest.  Your program must output a single time, namely the latest time when Joseph has to be on station A.

The transfer at B is immediate, so if the first train arrives to B at exactly the same time as the second train departs from B then Joseph can transfer.  You can assume that there are enough trains that Joseph can arrive at the required time or earlier.  You can also assume that each schedule is sorted by departure time, but you cannot assume that the schedule is sorted by arrival time.  For example, in the example input below, the first train from B departs at time 319 (meaning 09:27) and arrives at time 567 (meaning 9:27), but the second train departs at 366 and arrives at 539, overtaking the first train.  Joseph is in a hypothetical country where trains always run exactly in time according to their schedule.

Here's a non-golfed example solution in Python 3.  The function `transfer` solves the problem.  The function `travel` takes just one schedule and finds when you have to arrive to the station where the trains in that schedule start.

```
def travel(schedule, arrival):
    departure = -2000
    for train in schedule:
        if train[1] <= arrival and departure < train[0]:
            departure = train[0]
    return departure
def transfer(schedule0, schedule1, arrival1):
    return travel(schedule0, travel(schedule1, arrival1))
```

Here's how we invoke the above example solution with an example input triple.

```
print(transfer(
    ((270, 294), (337, 357), (390, 414), (457, 477), (510, 534), (577, 597), (630, 654), (697, 717), (750, 774), (817, 837), (870, 894), (937, 957), (990, 1014), (1057, 1077), (1110, 1134), (1230, 1254), (1338, 1362)),
    ((319, 567), (366, 539), (540, 714), (545, 809), (780, 954), (785, 1055), (900, 1074), (905, 1169), (1025, 1280), (1140, 1324)),
    720))
```

This prints `510`, which is the correct output for these inputs.  In station A, Joseph will take the train at time 510 (meaning 08:30), arrive to B at time 534 (08:54), get on the second train at time 540 (09:00), and arrive to C at time 714 (11:54), which is not later then the deadline time 720 (12:00).

This is a slightly modified version of [an easy programming homework problem that I posed many years ago](http://wiki.math.bme.hu/view/Informatika1-2010/Hazi4).  I am shamelessly copying the single example input from there, since I'm too lazy to make up a new one.

Golf Sandbox, besides all the other feedback, please tell me what tags I should use.

Comment: This would benefit from test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [RADD decomposition of an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256224/radd-decomposition-of-an-integer)

Comment: What are the winning criteria?

Comment: @pajonk I might add [tag:fastest-code], and then use time to decompose some big problems as a criteria. n in the range 400000 - 1000000. However, I don't know how to provide a comparison environment for the many languages used here. But I suspect that only non-naive methods with a better than linear time complexity have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

## [Friend or Foe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256050/friend-or-foe)

Comment: Since "Foe" is short they'd rather include in both program

Comment: @l4m2 Good point. Maybe something like "this program is, in fact, a foe"?

Comment: Still don't think it a good idea, slicing is easy in lots of languages

Answer (score 1):

## [Maximum of outer product of integer vectors
(in linear time)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256291/maximum-of-outer-product-of-integer-vectors-in-linear-time)

Comment: I think the dyadic product as better known as the outer product. Still, it is really needed to define the problem? I think it's easier understood as, "What's the largest product you can make by selecting one number from each list?"
A linear time seems OK to be me, but if you want a looser bound then polynomial time would be fine to eliminate the exponential brute-force solution.
For input, the site's convention is to leave it flexible, and allow, say, taking in a list of lists however those are formatting in the language. I'd also suggest limiting to integer-valued vectors.

Comment: @xnor thx for your suggestions. I have addressed all points and added your problem formulation as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

## [Is this position a pure mirror mate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255930/is-this-position-a-pure-mirror-mate)

Comment: I would add a test case where there is a white piece adjacent to the black king. I'd also add a test case just testing the guarding criteria. Otherwise I like it!

Comment: Suggested test case `8/R7/4k3/2P3P1/3K4/7B/8/8`. This passes all test criteria, apart from one square (C6) being attacked by the rook and guarded by the bishop, whereas your test case 2 would return False just from a test to see if there are more than two attackers per square

Answer (score 1):

## [Flip the order of operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255972/flip-the-order-of-operations)  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Your last test case (with the `2`) contradicts the specs (only operators, parens and letters).

Comment: @pajonk thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

[Find the smallest turing machine that solves the self-counting problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256211/find-the-smallest-turing-machine-that-solves-the-self-counting-problem)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange, and interesting first challenge! I've got some comments on your submission: 1) When you say "smallest TM", how are you measuring it? fewest number of states? 2) I think the last ${0,1}$ should be ${L,R}$. 3) How are you defining input and output? 4) I would also suggest giving more background information, not everyone understands the notation used.

I'm curious, does this "self-counting problem" exist in literature? (I'd be interested in articles/links.)

Comment: @user41805 thanks for the feedback, I came up with the problem myself, I don't think there is any literature on this problem. I'll edit my question to include your suggestions

Comment: Besides, try to keep your question a little more... *aligned* with common punctuation rules. It'll look better that way too. And besides, what's your scoring criterion?

Comment: @UndoneStudios it's seems like inline latex is not supported is there a link for common punctuation rules. the scoring is based on number of states of the turing machine

Comment: Alternatively output 0 and 1, claiming an encoding that fit it

Comment: 1) I meant using normal uppercase as well 2) So we have to write the code in a language that simulates a Turing Machine? Suggest using the code-challenge tag for this criterion.

Comment: @l4m2 I didn't understand what you mean can you clarify?

Comment: @UndoneStudios no you just have to find a transition function and an encoding for the transition function

Comment: So no programming languages required?

Comment: @raoof Also note that to fix your inline LaTeX use backslash to escape the `$`, like this: \$Q\$ -> `\$Q\$`

Comment: @UndoneStudios yes, no programming language is required. and thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of array of array of ..., convert it into a string. Brackets should be used to show depth.

However, the input may include loops (e.g. an array containing itself), which would lead to an infinite output without extra rule. Therefore, if an array has been expanded twice (and is trying to expand a third time), it should be expanded into something else.

Since some languages don't support recursive arrays, it's also allowed to take a list of list of indices \$[A_1,A_2,\ldots]=[[a_{11}, a_{12},\ldots],[a_{21},a_{22},\ldots],\ldots]\$, where each integer \$a_{ij}\$ should be replaced with the expanded array \$A_j\$.

Shortest code wins.

Test cases:

| raw | indices | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[]` | `[]` | `[]` |
| `[[],[]]` | `[1,1],[]` | `[[],[]]` |
| `A=[A,A]` | `[0,0]` | `[[-,-],[-,-]]` |
| `[A=[B],B=[A]]` | `[1,2],[2],[1]` | `[[[[[-]]]],[[[[-]]]]]` |

Function in javascript to convert indices into array:

```
function indices2array(arr) {
    var ret = arr.map(_=>[]);
    for (var i in arr) {
        for (var j of arr[i]) ret[i].push(ret[j]);
        ret[i].id = +i;
    }
    return ret[0];
}
```

---

Idea from recursive `iframe`. On Firefox, it expands using this rule.

[image]

```
A<br><iframe src="B.html"></iframe>
B<br><iframe src="A.html"></iframe>
X<br><iframe height="400" src="A.html"></iframe><iframe height="400" src="B.html"></iframe>
```

Given function that expands once, is it easy to expand twice?

Comment: What if my language does not support arrays that have themselves as sub-array? E.g. it is impossible to construct if you can't get a reference to (only the value of) an array.

Comment: @Adám Add explicit allowance

Comment: "Since some language don't support recursive array, it's also allowed to take a list of list of indices, each index meaning the responding list." feels like this sentence change the whole challenge into another one...

Comment: @tsh How? Just each `X[i]` => `C[X[i]]`

Comment: Is `a=[[[]]]; a[0][0][0]=[[[a[0][0]]]];` a valid testcase?

Comment: @tsh Should be covered by `[A=[B],B=[A]]`

Comment: I cannot understand your `[A=[B],B=[A]]`, is this some valid syntax in some language?

Comment: @tsh `x=[A=[],B=[]],A[0]=B,B[0]=A` input or `[
  <ref *1> [ [ [Circular *1] ] ],
  <ref *2> [ <ref *1> [ [Circular *2] ] ]
]
` output

Answer (score 1):

### No, thanks!

In the game “No Thanks!” playing cards numbered 3 to 35 are shuffled in a deck and 11 chips distributed to each player. The first player flips over a card and can then decide either to take the card, or to place a chip on top of it and to pass it on.

The card continues to be passed around until a player decides to take the card along with its chips. The same player flips over the next card and continues the procedure.

At the end of the game, the value of their cards get added up. Each chip they own is worth a negative point. The player with the lowest number of points wins.

Should a player have cards in succession (e.g. 18, 19, and 20), then the card with the lowest value (18) will be considered.

### Rules

- 9 cards will be removed from the deck at the start of the game
- You will be participating with 2 other players
- Everyone’s cards will always be visible
- You do not have access to the amount of chips that others possess. You can, however, keep track of them.

Answer (score 1):

## Calculate the McCombination

In 2002, McDonald's advertised a McChoice menu of 8 items, labelled with "40,312 combinations." However, this number is far greater than the actual number of combinations (255; 2^8=256, minus 1 for empty meal). What the McDonald's marketing team calculated was how many different ways you could *arrange* a meal containing all 8 items (8! = 40,320), but subtracted 8 from the total to remove 1-item combinations. Since their original calculation was incorrect, the final result is meaningless.

The [McCombination](https://oeis.org/A005096) of a number `n` is the factorial of `n`, minus `n`.

### Task:

Given an integer greater than 0 as input, output the McCombination of that number.

#### Test cases:

```
8 -> 40312
4 -> 20
9 -> 362871
3 -> 3
1 -> 0
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first challenge!

Comment: Seems a bit boring, most languages have built-ins for both parts of this

Comment: @mousetail do you think it would be better if it were something like “generate the first n McCombinayion numbers” or something

Comment: @Jacob that doesn't make it more interesting. Stacking trivial problems on top of each-other doesn't make a challenge interesting. Plus if you did that you'd no longer allow the standard [tag:sequence] rules

Comment: Alright then. So if this doesn't seem like a good problem, should I delete this post? Not very familiar with how the sandbox works @mousetail

Comment: You are free to delete or not delete, some people delete their posts others just abandon them. There's no convention one way or the other

Comment: Also don't be discouraged, my first few questions where terrible too

Comment: Okay thanks. I think I'll just leave this here then

Answer (score 1):

## [Form a subset that is a continuous range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256566/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Guess the song title](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256502/guess-the-song-title) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Answer (score 1):

## Division between two strings

[Inverse function of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125470/)

> To multiply two strings, you take two strings and compare each character. The character with the highest code point is then added to the output. If they are equal, simply add the character to the output.<sup>1</sup>

Given an input and the output, provide a random<sup>2</sup> input such that multiplying the two inputs returns the output. Each possible input should be possibly generated. If there's no possible input, output nothing or something that isn't a string(crashing is fine, but not infinite loop)<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1 I know it's not a `multiply` but that's copyed as-is</sup>

<sup>2 Otherwise a cat solves the question</sup>

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: How exactly should we generate with "random"?

Comment: @UndoneStudios Each possible input should be possibly generated.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further? Perhaps an example testcase?

Answer (score 1):

## [Implement a bag without replacement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256674/implement-a-bag-without-replacement)

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[data-structures](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: 1. You didn't specify what kind of randomness the answer needs to implement (see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/random/info and https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/55372) 2. About bonuses - they are discouraged - see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/55372.

Answer (score 1):

## WIP: clarify

Connect WEST and EAST using n pipe.

This is an example output, where n=9.

[image: n=9]

You can make sub-component, which each pin behave an extra pipe. Sub-component cost 2 pipe. Following is n=19. (The sub-component at the center is image above) You can also make sub-component in sub-component, and et infinitum.

[image: n=19]

It has same cost and behavior as

[image: n=19]

Thing change when n=35, where using sub-component only cost 33 pipe:

[image]

Now given odd n>8, output the minimum cost to connect WEST and EAST using n pipe.

```
9 => 9
19 => 19
35 => 33
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Capture the Flag... with a twist](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256964/114446)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the challenge. Could you add an example with a bit more explanation?

Comment: @Jacob - added. Let me know if I need to add another one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knook to Mate... With Portals!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257236/knook-to-mate-with-portals)

Comment: In [this image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/968416999808057344/1065835336002965554/image.png) you may want to mark someway that B3 can't be reached, right now you use the arrow both to mean inclusive range and just the endpoint

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/968416999808057344/1065836591588855909/image.png is d6 also valid?

Comment: @l4m2 d6 is indeed also valid. Positions may have multiple solutions

Answer (score 1):

## [Implement a 2Fuck Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/257017/91213)

Answer (score 1):

## Yet another Colatz challenge

### Background

We all know and love the colatz sequence. It goes like this:

- If a number is divisible by 2, divide by 2
- Otherwise, multiply by 3 and add 1.

The Colatz conjecture theorizes that if you repeat this process for any number, you'll eventually reach 1.

### Binary

If you write colatz numbers in binary, any numbers divisible by 2 will be followed by a 0. This means we can ignore any trailing 0s at the end of the number in binary notation, as the 0s will be removed first anyways. Thus we only need to consider the odd numbers. For the purpose of this challenge, we'll write it like this:

```
1[0]
```

This means "1 followed by any number of 0s". Every colatz number must pass through this number in this form at some point (since no odd number * 3 + 1 = 1). If we then subtract 1, we get this:

```
[1]
```

Then divide by 3 we get this:

```
[01]
```

Note that only even numbers of 1 are divisible by 3, so we only consider them. Here, we can prove that the last odd number in any numbers colatz sequence must be of this form. Of course, the ancestors in the same family will look like that:

```
[01][0]
```

### Continuing the pattern

We can continue the pattern to find general forms for the nth ancestor of 1 in the colatz sequence. We start like this:

```
-1 [01]00[1]
/3 [000111]00[01][0]
-1 [000111]00[01]00[1] (or if [01] is repeated 0 times [000111]00011011111[1])
/3 [000010010111101101000010010111101101]00[000111]00[01][0]
```

Note: Now, when subtracting 1 the pattern branches. Numbers inside the brackets can be repeated 0 or more times. If they are repeated at least once the 1 can "absorb" the `-1` from the right and prevent it from effecting the pattern to it's left. However, if repeated 0 times subtracting one would also flip the 0s to it's left until the first 1 is encountered. For the purpose of this challenge you only need to consider the branch of the path where each pattern is repeated at least once.

### The challenge

Your task is to output the general form of the nth-element in the odd only colatz sequence, assuming the branch where each pattern appears at least once.

- Output must be in binary
- You may use any reasonable method to mark which sequences can be repeated
- You may choose to output only the odd or only the even members of the sequence if you want
- You can loop forever, or output the nth element given a n, [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) rules

This is code golf, shortest code wins

Comment: Actually, I don't know the colatz sequence. I do know the Collatz sequence... ;P

Answer (score 1):

## [It's a dog!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257535/its-a-dog-maybe) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Comment: Picture show tail something like leg but don't touch floor; I usually see tail in real life touch floor with lot laid, though

Comment: You may want to specify that the legs need to be separate (i.e. cannot share a common "border"). As per the tail one option is to simplify the task only to check a simple tail (or a "tail ending"), e.g. `(space)_` \\ `[_` and the leftmost bracket touches the left border (and perhaps is the only non-space character there).

Answer (score 1):

## [Find Index of Rational Number in Calkin-Wilf Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260472/find-index-of-rational-number-in-calkin-wilf-sequence)

Comment: I think this is definitely different enough from the Stern-Brocot Tree

Answer (score 1):

## Output code to sort a list without looping [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

Given a integer `n`, output the source code for a program or function that can sort a list of `n` elements without looping. For any `n` there are a finite number of possible orderings so this has to be possible.

Looping includes any way to run code a variable number of times. It also includes recursion or using any built-ins that internally loop. (including your sort builtin) Branching is ok.

The code you submit may have loops, just the code outputted may not.

The lists you sort will be positive integers in the range \$ 1 \leq n \leq 2^{16} - 1\$. Note 0 is excluded. The list may contain duplicate elements.

For example:

| N | Possible Output |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `|x:&mut[u16;1]|()` |
| `2` | `|x:&mut[u16;2]|*x=if x[1]>x[0]{[x[0],x[1]]}else{[x[1],x[0]]}` |

Note the program you output can be as long as you like, your score is only the length of the program that generates the sorting function.

The program you output may be in a different language then the generating program, in this case list both languages in your header. Both may use any IO format from our standard input/output methods list.

Answer (score 1):

## Toggle my Comments [comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program which takes a string as input. If the string is a syntactically valid comment in the program's language, the program must output an uncommented version of the string. Otherwise, it must output a syntactically valid commented version. Programs may use either multiline or single-line comments. Languages that do not support comments may not compete.

#### Python example

````python
Input: spaghetti
Possible output: #spaghetti
Possible output: # spaghetti

Input: # spaghetti
Output: spaghetti

Input: #spaghetti
Output: spaghetti
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Toggle Hangul Vowel Harmony

(This post is partly [self-plagiarized](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194010/89459).)

### Objective

Given a Hangul syllable, toggle its vowel harmony.

### Introduction to Hangul syllables

Hangul(한글) is the Korean writing system invented by Sejong the Great. Hangul syllables are allocated in Unicode point U+AC00 – U+D7A3. A Hangul syllable consists of an initial consonant, a vowel, and an optional final consonant.

The initial consonants are:

```
ㄱ ㄲ ㄴ ㄷ ㄸ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅃ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅉ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ
```

The vowels are:

```
ㅏ ㅐ ㅑ ㅒ ㅓ ㅔ ㅕ ㅖ ㅗ ㅘ ㅙ ㅚ ㅛ ㅜ ㅝ ㅞ ㅟ ㅠ ㅡ ㅢ ㅣ
```

The final consonants are:

```
(none) ㄱ ㄲ ㄳ ㄴ ㄵ ㄶ ㄷ ㄹ ㄺ ㄻ ㄼ ㄽ ㄾ ㄿ ㅀ ㅁ ㅂ ㅄ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ
```

For example, `뷁` has initial consonant `ㅂ`, vowel `ㅞ`, and final consonant `ㄺ`.

### South Korean dictionary order

The consonants and vowels above are sorted in South Korean dictionary order. The syllables are firstly sorted by initial consonants, secondly by vowels, and finally by (optional) final consonants.

The Unicode block for Hangul syllables contains every consonant/vowel combinations, and is entirely sorted in South Korean dictionary order.

The Unicode block can be seen [here,](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAC00.pdf) and the first 256 characters are shown for illustrative purpose:

> 가각갂갃간갅갆갇갈갉갊갋갌갍갎갏감갑값갓갔강갖갗갘같갚갛개객갞갟갠갡갢갣갤갥갦갧갨갩갪갫갬갭갮갯갰갱갲갳갴갵갶갷갸갹갺갻갼갽갾갿걀걁걂걃걄걅걆걇걈걉걊걋걌걍걎걏걐걑걒걓걔걕걖걗걘걙걚걛걜걝걞걟걠걡걢걣걤걥걦걧걨걩걪걫걬걭걮걯거걱걲걳건걵걶걷걸걹걺걻걼걽걾걿검겁겂것겄겅겆겇겈겉겊겋게겍겎겏겐겑겒겓겔겕겖겗겘겙겚겛겜겝겞겟겠겡겢겣겤겥겦겧겨격겪겫견겭겮겯결겱겲겳겴겵겶겷겸겹겺겻겼경겾겿곀곁곂곃계곅곆곇곈곉곊곋곌곍곎곏곐곑곒곓곔곕곖곗곘곙곚곛곜곝곞곟고곡곢곣곤곥곦곧골곩곪곫곬곭곮곯곰곱곲곳곴공곶곷곸곹곺곻과곽곾곿

### Vowel Harmony

Korean vowels express **vowel harmony** as positive-negative pairs. They're paired like the followings:

```
(Positive) - (Negative)
ㅏ - ㅓ
ㅐ - ㅔ
ㅑ - ㅕ
ㅒ - ㅖ
ㅗ - ㅜ
ㅘ - ㅝ
ㅙ - ㅞ
ㅚ - ㅟ
ㅛ - ㅠ
(ㅡ, ㅢ, and ㅣ lack counterparts)
```

### Examples

- `뷁` → `봵`
- `냥` → `녕`
- `멍` → `망`
- `망` → `멍`
- `잌` → `잌`

Answer (score 1):

## [Determine the Octet(/Duplet/18-electron) Rule](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257650/determine-the-octet-duplet-18-electron-rule)

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)[chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

Answer (score 1):

[How to find the counterfeit coin?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257803/how-to-find-the-counterfeit-coin)

Answer (score 1):

An address is decoded as follow:

```
   reg eax ecx edx ebx esp ebp esi edi  0  sib
    id  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   -   -
+0      00  01  02  03  /   /   06  07  /   04
+imm8   40  41  42  43  /   45  46  47  /   44
+imm32  80  81  82  83  /   85  86  87  05  84
```

where sib means the following byte parsed as follow:

```
    +  eax ecx edx ebx esp ebp/imm32*esi edi
   eax  00  01  02  03  04     05     06  07
   ecx  08  09  0a  0b  0c     0d     0e  0f
   edx  10  11  12  13  14     15     16  17
   ebx  18  19  1a  1b  1c     1d     1e  1f
     0  20  21  22  23  24     25     26  27
   ebp  28  29  2a  2b  2c     2d     2e  2f
   esi  30  31  32  33  34     35     36  37
   edi  38  39  3a  3b  3c     3d     3e  3f
 2*eax  40  41  42  43  44     45     46  47
 2*ecx  48  49  4a  4b  4c     4d     4e  4f
 2*edx  50  51  52  53  54     55     56  57
 2*ebx  58  59  5a  5b  5c     5d     5e  5f
 2*esp  60  61  62  63  64     65     66  67
 2*ebp  68  69  6a  6b  6c     6d     6e  6f
 2*esi  70  71  72  73  74     75     76  77
 2*edi  78  79  7a  7b  7c     7d     7e  7f
 4*eax  80  81  82  83  84     85     86  87
 4*ecx  88  89  8a  8b  8c     8d     8e  8f
 4*edx  90  91  92  93  94     95     96  97
 4*ebx  98  99  9a  9b  9c     9d     9e  9f
 4*esp  a0  a1  a2  a3  a4     a5     a6  a7
 4*ebp  a8  a9  aa  ab  ac     ad     ae  af
 4*esi  b0  b1  b2  b3  b4     b5     b6  b7
 4*edi  b8  b9  ba  bb  bc     bd     be  bf
 8*eax  c0  c1  c2  c3  c4     c5     c6  c7
 8*ecx  c8  c9  ca  cb  cc     cd     ce  cf
 8*edx  d0  d1  d2  d3  d4     d5     d6  d7
 8*ebx  d8  d9  da  db  dc     dd     de  df
 8*esp  e0  e1  e2  e3  e4     e5     e6  e7
 8*ebp  e8  e9  ea  eb  ec     ed     ee  ef
 8*esi  f0  f1  f2  f3  f4     f5     f6  f7
 8*edi  f8  f9  fa  fb  fc     fd     fe  ff
* imm32 if no another imm
```

If an imm8 or imm32 is used, the value is followed after, little-endian.

Given a value of `{0,1,2,4,8}*reg+{reg,0}+imm32`, output a shortest expression of the address.

## Test cases

```
eax => 00
eax+8 => 40 08
eax+128 => 80 80 00 00 00
esp => 04 24
ebp => 45 00
4*eax => 04 85 00 00 00 00
2*eax => 04 00
2*esp => 04 60 00 00 00 00
```

## Sandbox Notes

- Since it's modified(enabled to allow `esp*4`), and I'd allow use of id, should I remove the `eax` expression?

Answer (score 1):

[Translate to plorcly borglar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257709/translate-to-plorcly-borglar)

Answer (score 1):

## [How spherical is my ellipsoid?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257853/how-spherical-is-my-ellipsoid)

Answer (score 1):

## [Random point inside boundary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257973/random-point-inside-boundary)

Answer (score 1):

## [Number Clusters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258044/number-clusters)

Answer (score 1):

[Find opposite string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257945/find-opposite-string)

Comment: What do you mean by “opposite mirror letter”

Comment: @Jacob "opposite mirror letter from the English alphabet" - it means that `a` must be replaced with `z`, `b` must be replaced with `y` and so on. In general let's we have some letter which index in alphabet is `Index`  then it must be replaced with letter which index is `25 - Index` (25 if zero based and 26 if 1 based)

Answer (score 1):

## [3D rotation matrix to quaternion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258001/3d-rotation-matrix-to-quaternion)

Answer (score 1):

Given a signed int64, convert into base -2 integer. `+ - & | ^ ~` cost 1. `=`, variable name, constant are free. Other operations disallowed. Lowest cost win.

[atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Injectively saturate bit strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258046/110698)

Answer (score 1):

[Elevator movement order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258137/elevator-movement-order)

Comment: Is it possible to have the first input also in the array? If so, how to handle that case?

Comment: @pajonk Can you please explain why do you need only first input in array and why not all inputs in one array? I don't like to mix the inputs because they separated by meaning

Comment: I meant a test case like `0, 3, [0,4,-2,-5,2,-4,1,5] --> ?` - where to sort the `0` from the array? Or such input combination will never appear? Also, will the array never contain duplicates?

Comment: @pajonk 1. The zero is the floor where elevator already stopped it can not be in the order of future destinations. 2. There can not be a duplicates, also in the input array can not be the same number as in second input because this floor already exist in the order. Please inform me if this information MUST BE in challenge, I will add it :)

Comment: I think not specifying those conditions in the challenge body may prompt similar questions on main, so yes, please add it :)

Comment: @pajonk Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Consolidate a 6-axis Vector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258395/60042)

Comment: I suggest specifying that the input will contain only integers. Also, as I read it, there is always one Consolidated Vector for any given input - is it the case?

Comment: @pajonk good points, I've added that information. Yes, there is only valid valid solution per input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Simultaneously solve N-queens and no-3-in-line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258173/110698)

Answer (score 1):

## [Animate the shape!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258599/shape-animation)

Comment: Nice challenge idea! You might want to add some examples.'

Answer (score 1):

[Sum of strings (UTF-16 codepoints)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258550/sum-of-strings-utf-16-codepoints)

Comment: I thought this was a dupe but can't find anything that really matches this. By "the module of sum by the 65536" do you mean "the sum, modulo 65536"?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, exactly. If you can rephrase this sentence correctly, I will be grateful to you!

Comment: If the resulting sum is greater than 65535 (maximum UTF-16 codepoint), take the sum \$\mod{65535}\$

Answer (score 1):

[Decoding a non injective bit matrix encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258547/decoding-a-non-injective-bit-matrix-encoding)

Comment: Is the size always even? If not, how do you define quadrants?

Comment: The side can be odd, in which case the boundaries are obtained by dividing the side length and flooring it. I've edited the statement to clarify this, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

## [Simulate Just Friends](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258738/110698)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangularly embed a graph on a surface](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258918/triangularly-embed-a-graph-on-a-surface)

Answer (score 1):

## Arbitrary numeric base as string

Given a positive integer `n` and an integer base `b` where `1<b<96`, please convert `n` into a string that represents its value in base `b`.

For a given base `b`, the following should hold:

- Digits should only have place value between `0` and `b`.
- Digits should be output in order from most significant to least significant.
- Digits with place value `0` to `9` should be represented with the ASCII characters `"0"` to `"9"`.
- Digits with place value `10` to `15` can be represented with your choice of ASCII characters `"a"` to `"f"` or `"A"` to `"F"` (but not a mix).
- Digits with place value 16 to 94 can be represented with your choice of the remaining ASCII characters, but they must be deterministic for a given base `b`.

Examples:

```
250, 5 -> "2000"
250, 16 -> "fa" or "FA"
250, 80 -> "3a" or "3A"
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: You should clarify in "Digits should only have place value between 0 and b." that 0 is inclusive and b exclusive

Answer (score 1):

## [Find the linear transformation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259357/find-the-linear-transformation)

Answer (score 1):

## Vertically Aligned JSON formatting

We have a question on JSON formatting on this site before, however, this one requires a different formatting convention.

Arrays should be formatted with the first element on the same line as the opening `[`, and the final `]` should be on the same line as the `]`. All other elements should be on separate lines, aligned with the first. Commas go on the end of each line except the last. like this:

```
["alpha",
 "beta",
 "gamma",
 "delta"]
```

Objects are mapped the same, but the values must also be aligned. There must always be at least one space between the `:` and the value, like this:

```
{"alpha":   "beta",
 "gamma":   "delta",
 "upsalon": "sigma",
 "iota":    "zeta"}
```

When structures are nested, they are aligned with their first element, like this:

```
[{"iota":  "beta",
  "gamma": "sigma"},
 {"zeta": {"meena": "kim",
           "vot":   "dilinia"}}]
```

Note  how separate objects do not need to align with each other, only keys in the same object align.

We will consider only 3 types: arrays, objects, and strings. Handing of numbers and null is optional.

Input is a mimified JSON string, you should output a vertically aligned JSON string with the same data. You do not need to preserve key order. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242999/100664)

Comment: It's vaguely similar for array formatting but completely different for object formatting

Comment: That's why I said related.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hyperjumps Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259793/lets-go-on-a-hyperjumping-trip)

Answer (score 1):

## Is it a hyperjump?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

*Easy-mode of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259793/108687)*

A *hyperjump* is a sequence of numbers 0-9 (exclusive), where:

- The first two digits can be any two
- Each number after is the result of a simple math operation (*, /, +, -) on the previous two.

  - E.g. [3, 2] → 3+2=**5**, 3-2=**1**, 3*2=**6**, 3/2=*not an integer*
  - If the result is multiple digits, take the last one. E.g. [7, 5] → 7+5=1 **2**, 7*5=3 **5**
  - The third- and second-most-recent digits may combine to one number and be used. E.g. [4, 1, 3] → 41-3=3 **8**, …
- The sequence should end with 9. There is no 9 in the list, but it should be able to be there by the rules outlined above.

For example, the sequence 7, 4, 3, 1, 2 is a hyperjump because 7-4=3, 4-3=1, 3-1=2, 31-2=9.

Your task is: Given a sequence of digits 1 through 8 inclusive, determine whether it is a valid hyperjump. You may output a truthy/falsy value, or choose two distinct values. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission in bytes per language wins.

---

Meta: I don’t have time to add test cases right now, I want to make sure this isn’t too similar to the other challenge before working on it more.

Answer (score 1):

## [Determine NBA conference seedings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259890/110698)

Answer (score 1):

## Draw a Regular Reuleaux Polygon

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126078/108687)*

A [Reuleaux polygon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_polygon) is a [curve of constant width](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width) made up of [circular arcs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_arc) of constant radius. The most well-known Reuleaux polygon is the [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle), which has three sides. In this challenge, you will be tasked to draw a regular Reuleaux polygon of a given number of sides.

A Reuleaux polygon is constructed by taking a polygon and replacing each of its sides with an arc centered at the opposite vertex.

This sort of shape can only be constructed from a polygon with an odd number of sides, so your input will be an odd number greater than or equal to three.

| Reuleaux pentagon (5 sides) | Reuleaux heptagon (7 sides) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: constructed pentagon] | [image: constructed heptagon] |
| [image: pentagon] | [image: heptagon] |

The circles in the first row are shown to demonstrate the construction; Your program's output should be closer to that of the second row (though the border and center mark are optional.)

Given a odd number ≥ 3, draw a regular Reuleaux polygon with that many sides.

Answer (score 1):

## Single Transferable Vote (Ranked Choice Vote)

Single transferable vote is a algorithm for selecting the best N candidates from a set of ranked choice votes. It works like this:

- Every voter must rank every candidate, first to last
- Let the voting threshold be the number of voters divided by the number of available positions
- While less than N candidates have been elected:

  - If the candidate with the most #1 votes has more votes than the threshold, elect them. Then remove that candidate from every voters ballot.
  - If no candidate has enough votes to be elected, eliminate the candidate with the lowest number of votes choosing them as #1. Remove this candidate from every ballot. In case of a tie tiebreaker is how often they are ranked #2, then #3 etc.

Given a list of votes, the number of open positions, and optionally a list of candidates, output which candidates get elected. Order doesn't matter.

You do not need to implement the algorithm above exactly as long as the result is the same.

### Test Cases

```
Positions: 2
Votes: [1,2,3]
       [2,3,1]
       [3,2,1]
Outcome: 2, 1
```

More test cases TBD

Answer (score 1):

## Countdown solver

### Input

An array of up to 6 integers, value 1..100, and a target integer 1..999

### Output

A series of mathematical operations (in any sensible format), using each of the integers in the input array 0..1 times, and the mathematical operators `+-*/` any number of times, to reach the target integer.

Intermediate operations may result in floats (e.g. `(3/2) * 4 = 6`), and there is no guarantee that the target is reachable at all (in which case the output is undefined). The input integers may not be concatenated (e.g. `1, 2` can't be used as `12`)

### Win criteria

Code golf, usual exclusions apply.

Comment: Is this a dupe of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6417/58563)?

Comment: @Arnauld yes, looks like it might be. Oh well. Unless anyone thinks it's suitably different with a variable length input?

Comment: It would be great if you can somehow make this one different enough, as the other challenge is quite old and didn't receive much attention.

Answer (score 1):

## Langton's Ant

Langton's ant is a simple two-dimensional universal Turing machine. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant):

> Squares on a plane are colored variously either black or white. We arbitrarily identify one square as the "ant". The ant can travel in any of the four cardinal directions at each step it takes. The "ant" moves according to the rules below:
>
> At a white square, turn 90° clockwise, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit
>
> At a black square, turn 90° counter-clockwise, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit

In this challenge, you will be given three inputs:

- A 2D square grid \$G\$ of two distinct symbols, where one represents a black cell and the other represents a white cell
- A coordinate \$(x,y)\$ representing the location on the grid where the ant starts
- A number of steps \$n\$

Your code should then return the grid after the ant starting at \$(x,y)\$ and *facing upwards*, completes \$n\$ steps.

You can use any reasonable form of indexing to describe the intial location of the ant on the grid (e.g. 0-based or 1-based).

You can assume that the ant will not attempt to go off the side of the grid at any point during the given steps.

#### Test cases

For these tests, I will assume that \$(0,0)\$ is the top-left corner of the board. I will also use `0` to represent a white cell and `1` to represent a black cell.

| \$G\$ | \$x\$ | \$y\$ | \$n\$ | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[[0]]` | 0 | 0 | 0 | `[[0]]` |
| `[[1]]` | 0 | 0 | 0 | `[[1]]` |
| `[[0,0],[0,0]]` | 0 | 1 | 1 | `[[0,0],[1,0]]` |
| `[[0,0],[0,0]]` | 0 | 1 | 2 | `[[1,0],[1,0]]` |
| `[[0,0],[0,0]]` | 0 | 1 | 3 | `[[1,1],[1,0]]` |
| `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` | 1 | 1 | 7 | `[[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1600/91213)

Comment: Title appears to be a typo, should be Langton's ant, rather than Langston's ant?

Comment: @ATaco Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Get all URLs on an HTML webpage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260492/get-all-urls-on-an-html-webpage)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sanitize the Spaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260646/sanitize-the-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

## A Graphical Degree Sequence?

Write the shortest program to determine if a degree sequence is graphical.

Given a sequence of numbers `S`, output a Boolean value representing whether or not a graph with `S` as its degree sequence exists.

The [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of a graph is a sequence representing the degrees of each of its vertices. The degree of a vertex is the number of edges connected to it. Generally the degree sequence is given in non-increasing order, but for this challenge, it may be specified in any order. This means that graphs may have multiple degree sequences.

**Example**

The following graph has a degree sequence of `[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]` or any of its reorderings.

[image: A Graph]

Some degree sequences like `[3, 3, 3, 2]` are impossible. If you try to draw such a graph, it becomes clear why.

**Test cases**

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1] -> True
[3, 3, 3, 2] -> False
[] -> True
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] -> True
[4, 4, 2, 4] -> False
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2] -> False
[3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4] -> True
[3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2] -> True
[0, 0, 0] -> True
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 6] -> False
[2, 4, 2, 2, 2] -> True
[4, 4, 3, 2, 4] -> False
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259143/is-it-a-valid-chemical), but not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Evaluate Minkowski's question mark function at rational numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/260804/110698)

Comment: Could you please add some worked-out examples?

Comment: @pajonk One example is there now.

Answer (score 1):

## Draw any infinite fractal [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

Write a function that, given as input 2 positive integers for X and Y, outputs one of two distinct values, representing white and black. Your function should have the following properties:

- No horizontal or vertical ray should infinitely repeat itself. A ray is a straight line that starts at one point then continues upto infinity. Mathematically \$ \not \exists x, y, \delta : \forall e \geq y+\delta: f(x,e)=f(x,e-\delta)\$ and the same with \$x\$ and \$y\$ reversed.
- Large scale structure: For every positive integer Z there exists a ZxZ square that is entirely white and also a ZxZ square that is entirely black. This rule ensures no matter how much you zoom out you should still be able to see some shapes and not just grey.

For the purpose of this challenge you may ignore the numerical limits of your language. When proving that your function meets the requirements, assume they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

## Output subsequent powers of two

[Output endless powers of 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261325/output-endless-powers-of-2/)

Comment: You should clarify if the program must circumvent floating-point data type limitations. Those limitations prevent large powers of 2 to be output accurately. That is, must the program handle arbitrarily large powers _exactly_? From our default rules (see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18196/36398) and [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/36398)) it could be interpreted that that's not necesssary. In any case, for this challenge I think it's better to be explicit about that

Comment: Perhaps another goal would be better, EG. A decision problem per [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25700/could-a-new-is-it-a-power-of-2-question-escape-being-closed-as-a-duplicate/25704#25704) discussion.

Comment: @ATaco It isn't a decision problem, as it is asking for subsequent powers of two, rather than testing if it is a power of two. (If I'm understanding your question correctly)

Comment: I was suggesting this *should* be a decision problem challenge instead of an infinite sequence, as it better handles what I perceive to be the bulk of the challenge.

Comment: @ATaco It intentionally is open either to doing it by incrementing numbers and outputting if it's a power of two (your way, it seems), or doubling (as in my example). Doubling wouldn't work if it were a decision problem.

Comment: I could just start at 0, which is 2 to the minus infinity, and always print 0.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian 0 doesn't count as a power of 2.

Comment: @Dadsdy enter `print(2**float('-inf'))` into Python IDLE

Comment: infinity is also a power of 2. It is 2 to the power of infinity.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian Fair points. Now zero and infinity as starting points are no longer valid. Also removed ability to multiply by 4 each time.

Comment: zero is finite. i would change the wording to "any finite non-zero power of 2".

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian It couldn't be zero, as it has to output subsequent powers of two, (which would be always 0), and it has to output each sufficently large power of two after finite time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Split a string on unnested commas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261554/split-a-string-on-unnested-commas)

Answer (score 1):

## Print every finite string

In this challenge, you're given the task to create a full program that generates and prints strings indefinitely. The strings must be printed on separate lines, and every finite string must (theoretically) be printed in finite time.

### Rules

- Your submission must be a full program, not a function.
- You must output the strings to STDOUT.
- There should be a single line feed between each string.
- A string is a sequence of printable ASCII characters (0x20-0x7e, inclusive). You may also include any number of null-terminators (0x0), EOFs (0xff) or other zero-space characters.
- The algorithm used must theoretically print any finite string in finite time. In practice, however, your program may fail after having printed at least 65535 strings.
- No string can be printed twice. Zero-space characters don't count as part of the string, so the program cannot output both `Hello` and `Hello(EOF)`.
- The empty string may or may not be generated.

#### Valid strings:

```
Hello
AAAA
(space)
Hello(EOF)
Hello, World!
"#(){ :|~A
```

#### Invalid strings:

```
(tab)
(newline)
ë
ñ
ø
π
```

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation)

Comment: I've posted a similar challenge [Output all strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74273/output-all-strings) though it takes the character set as an input

Comment: Does the program have to be deterministic? Or, Is it valid that for any string my program will output it with a probability of 1? The second one is simply `repeat forever { s=generate random string; if (s not yet printed) { print(s) } }`.

Comment: @xnor I didn't know of that challenge, thanks for notifying me :) I don't think I'll post this one, considering how similar it is to yours.

Comment: @tsh If all submissions had to be deterministic, they could just set the seed for functions generating random things, so I don't think I'll impose such restriction.

Answer (score 1):

## [Output every second](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262205/output-each-second/)

Comment: [tag:time] is a synonym for [tag:date], so maybe not what you want here. I'd also be unsurprised if this is a duplicate, though I'm not certain off the top of my head.

Comment: @Bbrk24 The tag says "This challenge is intended to be solved using [...] clock times", so it should still be fine (maybe). If there are any other tags you think belong on this len be know. I searched, and didn't find any others that are the same.

Answer (score 1):

### Counting black and white piano keys

Given a major or minor triad (3 note chord) name, return the amount of black and white piano keys needed to play it. (I will add more explanation later)

---

*Little bit of music theory*

A piano contains 88 keys: 52 whites and 36 blacks. The keys are divided into octaves which have 7 white keys and 5 black. The notes represented by the white keys go from A to G (although the starting note in an octave is C; notes from left to right are as following: C, D, E, F, G, A, B). The notes represented by the black keys are accidentals of the white keys. An accidental is either a sharp note (#) or a flat note (b). **(There is an exception since there is only 5 black keys and 7 white keys, Should I expand on this?)** . A sharp note is one semitone higher than the same note (C# is one semitone higher than C). A flat note is one semitone lower (Db is one semitone lower than D).  There is one full tone in between notes except for E-F and B-C where there is a semitone instead and one semitone between keys.

*I'll keep adding more details if needed*

Note: For this challenge, we don't care which octave the triad is played on since it will be the same answer for any octave.

**Example**

```
Cmaj  = 3 white, 0 black 
Fmin  = 2 white, 1 black
G#maj = 1 white, 2 black
Gbmaj = 0 white, 3 black
```

Input can be the chord name or can be divided into 2 variables: Root (C, F, G#, Gb) and quality (maj, min). I will extend on music theory if this is accepted as a good challenge

Output must be an array of 2 position where the first one is the number of white keys and the second one the number of black keys

---

Has this been asked before?

Comment: Looks like a nice challenge idea. But, as you say in your post, this definitely needs more music theory to explain what the major/minor triad names really mean. PS: Welcome back!

Comment: @Arnauld An usual explaination is just `[0,3,7]` and `[0,4,7]`, which is enough here

Comment: @Arnauld thanks mate! Good to be back. I have to research more into this challenge (I know music theory but I dont know how to explain it very well) therefore I'll leave here until my inspiration comes back. I have another idea tho I'll be posting soon!

Answer (score 1):

## [Draw the initial positions of Mölkky pins in ASCII Art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262428/draw-the-initial-positions-of-m%c3%b6lkky-pins-in-ascii-art)

Comment: I'm afraid this won't lead to many creative answers. Even with a short clever formula generating the pin numbers in the correct order, the cost of applying the correct formatting is very likely to give something longer than just hardcoding the output (for standard languages) or using a built-in string compression (for esolangs).

Comment: @Arnauld Sadly i found the same conclusion while trying to code it. For standard languages, would it be more interesting if i discouraged hardcoding by discouraging using too many digits, for example with a scoring system? (for esolangs, i think it's part of the game that anything goes and i shouldn't try to oppose it)

Comment: This is usually a [bad idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/58563). Maybe it would be better to turn this into a slightly more complex ASCII art, giving more compression opportunities. [Here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Q8ECkAQH49McgGxvoF5DIi0BJMWQJJL38AUxDE0BJNGYAmzGK4aBQV9A2OwmAFYzCRGQaEGJAyWMYwBkUYxYC5QOD4eIoNAQBEuBQiNTILEUIQB) is a quick attempt.

Comment: [Alternate version](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Q8ECkAQH49McgGxhoG5Joi0BJMWQJJLw8AUxDE0BJNGYAkzTa4aBQUNA2OwmAFYzERTQaEGJAyWMdQEkUaaYC5QOD4eIoNAQBEuBQiNTILEUIQB)

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you for your input. I've changed the challenge with your alternate version. I still hope that this would allow some clever and competitive formulas for the pins numbers!

Answer (score 1):

## [Critical Calculations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262682/critical-calculations)

Comment: Computing the damage per ring instead of just the total damage seems like an unnecessary transformation, perhaps allow both?

Comment: @CommandMaster Fair point, I think I will allow both

Answer (score 1):

## [Landmine Number IV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262746/landmine-number-iv)

Answer (score 1):

## Tableing in 3 operations

[There was a puzzle requiring to convert EBCDIC into ASCII in 4 operations.](https://research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/December2015.html) Actually, if big integers are allowed, 3 mathematical operations(so no bit shift, integer division, etc.) is enough, even for more complex mapping.

Given an array \$\left[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\right]\$, generate arguments \$a,b,c\$, such that \$ \forall 0 < k \le n, a \mod \left(bk+c\right) = x_k\$.

Fastest algorithm wins. Here word RAM model is used: bitwidth is by default \$\text O \left (\log \max\left\{ x_k, n\right\} \right)\$. You can cost \$2^t\$ time to extend the bitwidth to \$\text O\left(t\right)\$ without extra code. BigInts are treated as multiple ints, and take longer time to process larger values.

## Sandbox Notes:

- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) or [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)?

Comment: 1. `Sandbo xNotes` should be `Sandbox Notes`.
2. Your challenge needs a title
3. This might be confusing to people without a mathematical background, so you should probably explain it in plain English.

Answer (score 1):

## Tic-Tac-Toe: Maintain the Draw!

Tic-Tac-Toe is a game for two players who take turns marking the spaces in a `3x3` grid with an `X` or an `O`. If a player succeeds in placing three of their marks in a horizontal, vertical or diagonal line they are the winner; otherwise, the game is considered drawn.

## Challenge

You have been chosen to represent the human race in a game of Tic-Tac-Toe against the AIs. Dauntingly, your opponent is a programme which always finds the optimal move in a given position. Worse still, you will be playing second. The only consolation is that you are required to survive for one move only: that is, you must make a single move in reply to the computer's opening gambit which leads to a position which is not theoretically lost. If you find such a move, humanity lives to fight another day; if not, ...

Assuming a Tic-Tac-Toe board with the following notation

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

given the AI's opening move output all possible replies which do not lead to a theoretically lost position.

## Input

An integer \$n\$ (where \$1<=n<=9\$) which represents the machine's opening move as per the given board notation.

## Output

A sorted list, array, etc. of integers which represents all possible solutions.

## Explained Cases

```
Input => Output

1 => [5]
The only reply to a corner-square opening move which does not lead to a theoretical loss
is that which occupies the central square.

2 => [1, 3, 5, 8]

The only replies to an edge-square opening move which do not lead to a theoretical loss
are those which occupy the same row or column as that of your opponent's move.

5 => [1, 3, 7, 9]

The only replies to a central-square opening move which do not lead to a theoretical
loss are those which occupy one of the four corner squares.
```

## Test Cases

```
Input => Output

1 => [5]
2 => [1, 3, 5, 8]
3 => [5]
4 => [1, 5, 6, 7]
5 => [1, 3, 7, 9]
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Answer (score 1):

## [Print all polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263200/print-all-polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

## Write a Turing machine that draws this fractal

*This challenge is inspired by and similar to my [other challange](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25885#25885) about a fractal matrix, but uses a slightly different matrix (for n up to 3 the matrices are nearly the same, but for n >= 4 they start to differ more significantly)*

---

A 2D-Turing machine is like a regular [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) but the memory tape is 2 dimensional, meaning that after each step you can in addition to moving left or right also move up or down.

[...]

Your task is to create a 2 dimensional Turing machine that prints the infinite fractal matrix generated by the following procedure:

- Start with a single cell, set it to `1`
- repeat `n` times:

1. add a copy of the previous matrix to the left of the previous matrix
2. add a copy of the previous matrix below the previous matrix
3. add a copy of the previous matrix with `1` and `0` swapped, diagonally to the bottom right of the previous matrix.

First few steps:

```
n=0:

1

n=1:

1 1
1 0

n=2:

1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1

n=3:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0

n=4:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

Rules:

- It is allowed to output/display any two (distinguishable) distinct cells values for the two different values in the matrix
- Cells inside the matrix have to have the correct value more that 50% of the time (\$\lim_{steps \to \infty} \frac{correct}{steps} >0.5\$)
- Cells outside the matrix should be empty more that 50% of the time.
- The score of an answer is the number of distinct cell values used times the number of states of the Turing machine
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the solution with the lowest score wins

related: [generate the matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162254/generate-a-walsh-matrix)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

---

## Meta:

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is my explanation clear?
- Should I link to an example implementation of a 2D Turing machine?

Comment: I feel like saying "it differs for n>=4" suggests you might want an example for n = 4 at least :)

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162254/9288)

Answer (score 1):

### WumpusWars King of the Hill

This is probably going to stay in the sandbox for a few weeks, until I get the time to write the actual scoring code up... Yep, I'm both lazy and busy :P  I'm not very good at coding challenges but I'm good at thinking up creative ideas, so this time my idea is to try reviving the genre of KotH, as the last one on this site (Crazyhouse Chess) has been very unsuccessful (0 submissions for pretty obvious reasons) and the others are all many months old...

Inspired by Hunt the Wumpus, an early command line game. It is somewhat popular among esolang communities as a programming challenge, especially for languages like Befunge. However, the original, singleplayer version is boring, so I wanna upgrade it. Hence I created WumpusWars, a better version of it!

Story: You are a brave hunter in a dark cave, trying to kill the Wumpus, a mysterious monster. You start with 5 arrows that can kill the Wumpus if you shoot the arrow into the same room as the Wumpus. The cave consists of large rooms and small passageways in between. It can be represented, hence, with a graph, so that the rooms are nodes/vertices and the passageways are edges. There are a total of 50 vertices in the graph, each of them having a degree of at least 3, and the graph is guaranteed to be connected. Rooms are numbered from 0 to 49. You are spawned in a random room.

The place is so dark that you cannot see anything, but you can feel, smell, and hear. Hence you have access to the functions listed in the source code below. Lemme explain what the functions are associated with in more detail:

1. Bats: There are 5 rooms in total that contain bats. Entering one of them will cause you to be carried away to a random empty room ("empty room" defined as a room without bats, pits, players, or the wumpus, but there can be corpses in the room).
2. Pits: There are 5 rooms in total that contain a pit. Entering one of them will cause you to BOOM! CLASH! CRACK!
3. Wumpus: It remains in its own room unless either an arrow is shot by anyone anywhere, or the game is in deathmatch mode (see gamemode list for explanation). If it enters your room then... You know what. When an arrow is shot or in deathmatch mode it moves randomly to adjacent rooms. Bats and pits do not affect it.
4. Players: Other players. Note that you cannot shoot a player in the same room as you because the arrow is magically explosive and shooting in the same room as your own will cause you to BOOM! CLASH! CRACK!
5. Corpse: When a player is killed by anything except a pit they become a corpse, and corpses don't move (obviously). You can collect arrows from the corpses, and if the corpse has already been arrow-collected there will be 0 arrows on it.

Also, every 10 rounds an arrow will spawn in an empty room. Entering that room will cause your number of arrows to be incremented by 1. Multiple arrows can spawn in the same room which gives you several at once, but that's pretty rare.

You need to write a player program in Python and submit it as an answer to the post. Use the "PlayerName" class template. You will have to define with the `participate` function which gamemodes are you participating in (the input to the function will be one of the abbreviation strings):

1. Singleplayer (abbrev: "SP"). Precisely what the name says. Your score is the percentage of games in which you win (by shooting the Wumpus with an arrow). You lose if you die. After 100 rounds the game enters deathmatch mode, where the Wumpus keeps moving randomly every round regardless of whether an arrow is shot.
2. Player vs Environment (abbrev: "PVE"). Same as singleplayer except that there are multiple players. The winner is the one who kills the Wumpus (if multiple players shoot it in the same round they split the point equally). If everyone dies then no one wins. Arrows have no effect on players. Deathmatch starts after 20*n rounds, where n is the number of players.
3. Player vs Player (abbrev: "PVP"). Kinda PVE inverted. The Wumpus is now immortal –– but the players are not! If you get shot by other players or get eaten by the Wumpus you die and lose. The last one standing is the winner. If multiple people die last in the same round they split the point equally. It's deathmatch from start to finish.
4. Among Us (abbrev: "IP" for Imposter and "CM" for Crewmate). The Wumpus is immortal. Some players become impostors. Others are crewmates. Impostors get 3 arrows at the beginning (number might change according to # of players). Crewmates start with no arrows (but can still pick randomly spawned arrows up). Crewmates are immune from arrows fired by other crewmates. If all impostors die then all crewmates (dead or alive) win a point. If all crewmates die then all impostors (dead or alive) win a point. No deathmatch.

If you have any ideas please lemme know!

Source code:

```
class Environment:
    def __init__():
        # Hidden
    def legal_moves(player) -> list:
        # Returns an ordered list of adjacent rooms
        # Example: [5, 8, 10]
    def bats(player) -> bool:
        # True if bats are in adjacent rooms, false otherwise
    def pits(player) -> bool:
        # True if pits are in adjacent rooms, false otherwise
    def wumpus(player) -> bool:
        # True if wumpus is in adjacent rooms, false otherwise
    def others(player) -> bool:
        # True if the shortest path from you to the nearest player passes at most 2 edges.
    def arrows(player) -> int:
        # Returns the number of arrows player has
    def corpse(player) -> list:
        # Returns a list of integers
        # The length of the list is the number of corpses in the player's room
        # Elements in the list are the number of arrows on each corpse
    # Other functions hidden
```

Template:

````
class PlayerName: # Change the name!
    def __init__(mode:str, room:int, env):
        # Gamemode. Such as 'SP'.
        self.mode = mode
        # Current room number.
        self.room = room
        # Environment
        self.env = env
    def participate() -> bool:
        # Add code here...
        
        # Return True if self.mode is a supported gamemode
        # False if not
    def action() -> tuple:
        legal_moves = self.env.legal_moves(self)
        bats = self.env.bats(self)
        pits = self.env.pits(self)
        wumpus = self.env.wumpus(self)
        others = self.env.others(self)
        arrows = self.env.arrows(self)
        corpse = self.env.corpse(self)

        # No methods or variables from Environment class allowed below here!
        # Suggested to first check which gamemode and use strats accordingly.

        # Add code here...

        # Return a tuple of type (bool, int)
        # The bool is True for shooting, False for moving
        # The int is the cave number to shoot or move to
        # An illegal move signifies doing nothing
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Efficiently solve quadratic equations when 1+1=0

*This is a sequel to my [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263452/solve-quadratic-equations-when-11-0) about solving quadratic equations in the shortest possible code, this challenge is about solving the same task the fastest possible way*

The goal of this challenge is to find a solutions for a general quadratic polynomial `ax²+bx+c`.
Meaning be an integer `r` such that `a*r*r+b*b+c` is zero, with `+` meaning exclusive or and `*` being carry-less multiplication (use xor as addition in binary long multiplication).

To simplify the problem, you can assume that both `a` and `b` are one, so you only have to solve equations of the form `r*(r+1)=n` for an integer `n`. *As any quadratic equation can be converted in this normal form, this is enough to solve the general case (up to linear transformations)*

Your challenge will be to solve this simplified equation in the most efficient way possible.

Input: An integer `n`
Output: A number `r` such that `r*(r+1)=n` with `*` being multiplication without carry and `+` being exclusive or.

Rules:

- You may assume there is an integral solution to the equation
- You only have to return one of the two roots (the other root will only differ in the last bit)
- You program should be able to handle inputs up to at least `0x5555555555555555aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
- The algorithm you are using should work for arbitrarily large `n`
- The program with the lowest time complexity in `n` wins
- For your score you can assume that xor-addition and xor-multiplication are computed in `O(1)` (even if your program might need `O(n²)` operations)
- If multiple programs have the same complexity, the shortest program (per language) wins

Examples (both possible solutions given):

```
6 -> 2 | 3
20 -> 4 | 5
18 -> 6 | 7
72 -> 8 | 9
78 -> 10 | 11
...
113427455640312821160607117168492587690 = 0x5555555555555555aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 0xfffffffffffffffe | 0xffffffffffffffff
```

### [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

## Meta

- Would this be an interesting challenge ?
- Should I extend the challenge to general polynomials (this can be done in O(1) multiplications/divisions after solving the original problem (or computing the normal square root in some cases))?
- Is the rule about multiplication&addition do not count towards the complexity clear?

Answer (score 1):

## Pack the sequence!

You have a list of sequences of numbers *(1 byte max, unsigned)* as an input, e.g.:

```
4 6 4 9 3 15 150
3 2 1
9 6 4 1
…
```

Your task is to pack as many of them as possible into the square composed from the numbers from this list - the size of square is also an input.

The square of size 4 may look like:

```
10 13 56 30
98 11 10  4
15 36 77 86
 1  1 45 11
```

The numbers may repeat as many times as you want.

The sequence is considered "packed" if you can draw the line from the first number inside square to the next adjacent number in sequence and so on. Each number may be used only once for a single sequence.

For example, the sequence `36 11 77 11` is packed into the square above - the number may have up to 8 adjacent numbers: top, left, right, bottom and diagonals. While the sequence `11 36 10 11` is not - since the same number 11 can't be used twice.

### Scoring

For the packed sequence of size S you get 2^S scores. Each sequence counts only once - even if you can pack it multiple times in the same square.

### Victory Condition

The algorithm wins if it outputs the square of expected size with the maximum scoring for some hidden test lists. The algorithm is expected to be general enough to work with any random list.

### Output

Program should output square as a sequence of numbers on a single line.
For example: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` is the square of size 3:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

### Limitations

- Any list contains [1, 1000000] sequences.
- Any sequence contains [N, 20] numbers, where N is size of square.
- The size of square N is [2, 10].
- Program should use no more than 1Gb of user-space memory.
- Program should work no more than 60 seconds and use a single thread.
- Program may output more than one square - one per line. The last full square after 60 seconds is considered the answer.

Comment: It's too likely that no two number is same, and best solution is trivial

Comment: How is it likely? Numbers are limited in [0, 255]. Max possible 1000000*20 = 2'000'000 numbers in the list - they are definitely likely to be the same. Also in some test scenarios specifically numbers can be tuned to be in much smaller interval like [0, 9] only.

Answer (score 1):

The New York Times have a new game -

## Letter Boxed

(try it at https://www.nytimes.com/puzzles/letter-boxed, the rules below match it).

The game consists of a square, with three Letters on each side. The aim of the game is to join the letters to make words. Each word must start with the last letter of the previous word; and each letter must not share a side of the square with the previous letter. The aim is to solve (use all of the letters at least once) in as few words as possible.

For example:

```
  H  E  M

O         U

S         R

W         N

  A  I  G
```

You could use all of the letters in one go to form the word `Housewarming`, but `Swim` would be forbidden because the S and the W are consecutive and share a side on the square.

Additionally, `HOUSE` followed by `ERGO` would be allowed, but `HOUSE` followed by `WARM` would not because they don't share a last/first letter (`E->W`).

Letters can be repeated (e.g. `WEARER`), but not sequentially (so `SEEN` is forbidden), because they share a side.

### The challenge

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), usual rules.

The aim is to write a program that takes in the set of letters in any reasonably form (a string, or an array of arrays, for example); along with a word list (or you can read the word list in your code for free).

The output should be a word of sequential list of words that solve the puzzle by using all of the letters at least once.

The puzzle will always be solvable for the letters and word list given, but not always in one word.

Answer (score 1):

## Challenge

Create a program that, when entered two numbers *A* as a numerator and *B* as a denominator, generates a list of equivalent fractions based off the fraction *A*/*B*.

## Definition

Equivalent fractions are any set of fractions that ***equal the same when converted to a decimal number.*** Example: 3/6 (three sixths), 2/4 (two fourths) and 1/2 (one half) are equivalent fractions, since each fraction equals 0.5 when converted to a decimal number.

## Rules

- Generate *only* the equivalent fractions with denominators smaller than *B*. Do *not* generate equivalent fractions with decimal points or negative numbers.
- Your output must look like this: (This example is for entering 10 as *A* and 20 as *B*)

```
1/2 2/4 3/6 4/8 5/10 6/12 7/14 8/16 9/18 10/20
```

- If you cannot generate equivalent fractions with denominators smaller than *B*, output *A*/*B* itself: (This example is for entering 1 as *A* and 2 as *B*)

```
1/2
```

- The answer with the lowest amount of bytes wins.
- You may use any programming language of your choice.

Comment: Ideally, you should provide all the information needed to participate in the challenge, rather than linking to an external resource (though you may provide links for supplemental materials or further reading). Also, what do you mean by "only the ones smaller than A/B", if they definitionally have the same value?

Comment: By smaller than "A/B" I meant having lower denominators. Sorry for the mixup

Comment: About the output formatting, I also recommend reading through [our I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). The first couple pages of answers (if you sort by highest score) are pretty much accepted; once you get to the third page it's more controversial, and I think you can safely ignore the answers with score 6 or lower.

Comment: You should add examples for the expected output given different inputs. For example: What should the program output for when the Input is `1 2`? Can `A` or `B` become negative, if yes what happens in that case?

Answer (score 1):

## [Optimal Duck Game Moves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264296/114446)

Comment: I would prefer if the instructions were in the post itself, they aren’t that long.

Answer (score 1):

## Comment Out the Comment

> I'm back! Lately I've been working on something, but finally I've
> finished it and can return to CGCC! I'll be continuing the [Fast &
> Golfiest Series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263049/cops-fast-and-golfiest-season-1-the-lord-of-the-strings) soon, and also try to start working on (given I have
> the time and energy) [WumpusWars](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25889/118810). For now, a new question as a gift for everyone!

In LaTeX if you type `%a`, the `a` would be commented out.
But if you type `\%a`, the `a` would still be there because the backwards slash converted the meaning of `%`.
And if you type `\\%a`, the `a` would be commented out because the first backwards slash converted the meaning of the second one.
So do you know what happens to the `a` if you type `\\\\\\\\\\\%\\\%a`? (Answer: The `a` is not commented out).

This is a code golf challenge so shortest code wins: the input is a string which consists exclusively of `\` and `%`, except that at the end there is always `%a`. Output `1` or `True` if the `a` is commented out, and `0` or `False` otherwise.

Comment: Is `\a` valid?.

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks for pointing that out! No. I'll add that `a` is always preceded by `%`.

Answer (score 1):

## [How Turing complete is you language?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264291/how-turing-complete-is-you-language)

Comment: The premise is good, but I don't think the definition of "syntax character" is helpful here. It just moves the problem from languages that have "all TC sets must contain X" to those that have "all TC sets must contain either X or Y".

Comment: @Bubbler Do you think allowing to reuse characters is bad in general (which would make solutions in most normal languages impossible) or do you think I have to improve my definition for which characters I allow to reuse.

Comment: Yes to the former. Arbitrary rules like that tend to not go well, mainly because there are so many different langs and different (often unexpected) ways they work. It isn't that trivial even in the case of Python (you can write nontrivial programs without whitespace). So let's just take the task literally and see what creative stuff people can come up with.

Comment: @Bubble you may be right, I tried to find two disjoint Turing complete sets in Python and the main limiting factors seems to be the letter `e`not `:` or `\n` as I previously expected

Answer (score 1):

## [The rectangle spanned by two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264504/the-rectangle-spanned-by-two-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

## [Multiply multivariate polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264589/multiply-multivariate-polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

## [Golf the fast growing hierarchy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264852/golf-the-fast-growing-hierarchy)

Comment: Looks like a really interesting challenge; but you might want to be careful with languages saying "oh but my biggest integer value is [X small number] so I only have to deal with that case"

Comment: @WD That would abuse the loophole "Abusing native number types to trivialize the challenge".

Answer (score 1):

## [Half even rounding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264663/half-even-rounding)

Comment: As far as I know, PowerShell and brev also use banker's rounding, and some languages like Jelly that may be similar/based on Python may have a built-in that's a "Python round() function" || also, you may want to specify that this is Python 3 behaviour

Answer (score 1):

## Print every Unicode character (almost) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

Print every Unicode character, except U+0000. Any order is allowed.

### Specification

Every Unicode character from U+0001 to U+10FFFF, inclusive.
Exclude U+D800 to U+DFFF inclusive as apparently these 'surrogates' cause weird behaviour.

To be honest, I don't know much about Unicode so before this gets posted someone will have to fill me in on how Unicode works

Comment: This might be more suitable as a CMC.

Comment: Please remove your edit in all caps and/or change it to not be in caps. This just clutters the post.

Comment: Does this include non-printable (e.g. U+00) / unassigned (e.g. U+D800-U+D8FF) Unicode characters?

Comment: What's a CMC? @Adám || EDIT: nvm found it "chat mini challenge"

Answer (score 1):

## Make a braille cribbage board

The braille characters lie in the range U+2800 (`⠀`) to U+28FF (`⣿`), making it a SBCS (**S**ingle **B**yte **C**haracter **S**et). Oddly enough, the braille patterns look a lot like holes in a cribbage board. Here is an image of one of the many cribbage boards for reference:

[image: Cribbage Board]

So you must print this pattern:

```
+-------+
|⣀⣀⠀⣿⠀⣀⣀|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿|
|⠉⠉⠀⣿⠀⠉⠉|
+-------+
```

Note that **the blanks are U+2800 and *NOT* the space**.

,? is ,7tag3code-golf7'1 s %orte/ code w9s6

Oh, we're not using grade 2 contracted braille. You're not blind.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[card-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-game)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Answer (score 1):

### Implement RAID

RAID, or Redundant Array of Independent Disks is a way to efficiently store data in such a way that if any one disk fails you can still recover the data. Instead of implementing the official protocol, any function that can preserve data counts.

Your task is to produce two functions.

The first is the encoder. Given N lists with M elements each, produce N+1 lists with M elements each. What these lists contain is up to you.

The second part is the recovery system. Take as input the lists produced by the encoded, except one is missing. You must be able to recover the original data no matter which of the lists is gone.

Each list should contain only integers between 0 and 255. It is your choice how to represent the empty list, for example you can:

- Replace it with an empty list
- Replace it with a non-list value like `None`
- Prefix all present lists with a 1 and the missing list with 0.
- Take as a separate input which list is missing then just zero out the values.

### Example

A basic XOR based solution could look like this:

Encoder:

```
def encode(list_of_lists):
    return [*list_of_lists, [reduce(lambda a,b:a^b, i) for i in zip(*list_of_lists)]]

def decode(list_with_one_removed):
    return [
        (i if i else [reduce(lambda a,b:a^b, j) for j in zip(*(k for k in list_with_one_removed if k))
        for i in list_with_one_removed
    ][:-1]
```

You don't need to use a XOR based solution, as long as you can extract the original data again your solution is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Simulate Round Robin Scheduling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265060/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sokobunny I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265221/119528)

Comment: You should definitely mentioned this is taken from the game Paquerette Down the Bunburrows

Comment: I think it might be good to start with a simpler challenge, like whether a sequence of moves wins, or even which way a bun runs in a single situation.

Comment: Edited the question, now I think this is going to be simple enough.

Comment: Guarantees: No buns were harmed during the making of this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Tamagochi

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
 <s>I can't believe there has never been a Tamagochi challenge on code golf!</s> Edit: There has never been a Tamagochi challenge, but there was a [Tamagotchi, whatever that is.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100906/make-a-simplified-tamagotchi-giga-pet)

## Rules:

- The output must begin with "You found an egg!"
- Text-adventure style tamagochi.
- Prints status changes to stdout.
- Three actions at any moment:

  - Rub/pet
  - Feed
  - Info
- At the start of the program, you must wait for an egg to hatch.
- If not fed for 4 minutes, pet moves down a hunger status
- If fed twice in 4 minutes, pet moves up a hunger status.

## Accommodations for golfing languages:

- The language can't access system time:

  - You now have to implement a command `wait x`, that waits for `x` minutes.
  - Each newline advances the time by 30 seconds.
- The language can't prompt:

  - Read the input from a file, and provide the file you used to test.
- The language can't read from files:

  - Well, that sucks. Maybe another lang?

### Info:

Shows the following:

- Pet name
- Pet age
- Pet hunger
- Pet happiness

## Pet Statuses/behavior:

```
Initial conditions: Hungry (0 food), Sad (0 pets), Age: 0s

Happy: The pet is happy. Transitions to sad in 3 minutes if no interaction.
Sad: Pet needs a petting within 2 minute or becomes sick. Takes t/15 pats to return to happy, where t is in seconds.

Hungry: Pet needs to be fed within 2 minutes, or becomes sick.
Overfed: Pet needs to not be fed more than twice in 4 minutes, or becomes sick. If currently sick and fed by player, advance death timer by 1 minute.
Fed: Reverses the death timer if not sad or dead.

Old: Pet's age + time not in "Happy" and "Fed" > 1h
Sick: Pet will die in 5 minutes, if status causing sick is not cured. If sick with no status, remove sick in one minute.

If a pet dies, prints name, condition(s) and time.
    "Mr. Johnson died of old age, 1h:23m"
    "Tamagotchi died of sadness 0h:7m"
```

The smallest Tamagochi wins.

## Example

The following is an example simulation, where `>`  could be a prompt, or other input as mentioned in accommodations.

Whenever a pet gains or loses a status, it must output
`{pet name} is no{w | longer} {status}`

```
Termagotchi
You found an egg!
...
The egg is hatching!
...
The egg has hatched!
What would you like to name your pet?
> Mr. Johnson
Mr. Johnson is now hungry.
Mr. Johnson is now sad.
> Info
Mr Johnson
Age: 13s
Hungry, Sad
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
Mr. Johnson is now fed.
Mr. Johnson is now happy.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
...
Mr. Johnson is now sad.
...
Mr. Johnson is now sick.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
> Pet
You petted Mr. Johnson.
Mr. Johnson is now happy.
> Info
Mr Johnson
Age: 14m:27s
Happy, Sick
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
...
Mr. Johnson is now not sick.
...
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
Mr. Johnson is now overfed.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
Mr. Johnson is now sick.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
> Feed
You fed Mr. Johnson.
Mr. Johnson died of overfed, 23m:11s
```

Comment: This isn’t TikTok, there’s no need to say “unalive”. There’s no special algorithm here (except HNQ); it just shows the most recently modified or answered question first.

Comment: Also keep in mind that popcons have been soft-banned here and don’t tend to be seen favorably.

Comment: This is heavily underspecified

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges: Bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106). It's also unclear how any of the rules should be implemented in a program.

Comment: @pajonk Is this still underspecified?

Comment: Still pretty underspecified. The introduction ("You found an egg!...") is unspecified, it's unclear whether the ">" prompt is necessary, the initial values for age/hunger/happiness are unspecified, none of the status change outputs are specified.

Comment: Also, the example suggests that languages must have both a way to "prompt" for input during the program's run and access to system time, which excludes certain classes of languages. Not that this is necessarily a bad thing, just something to consider.

Comment: Also, [related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100906/make-a-simplified-tamagotchi-giga-pet)

Answer (score 1):

## Fastest decimal to binary [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[Same challenge, but code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258397/number-to-binary)

Given a decimal number, your task is to convert it to binary.

### Test cases

```
8496867758 -> 111111010011100111110100110101110
28284301455933783441 -> 11000100010000110000001100101000101001000111111110011110110010001
701550526345030865283462565098928586836 -> 1000001111110010011011011101110100010101010100010110011100010101100110100000111111010100100011101000000011010011011100000001010100
```

### Rules

- You can take input either as a string containing decimal digits, or a list of decimal digits.
- You need to output the number in binary, either as a string containing the binary digits or a list of binary digits.
- You are allowed to have leading zeros in the output.
- The input won't contain leading zeros.

### Scoring

Your score is the maximum number of digits your code can handle in under a second on my computer (Intel Core i7-9700 with 8 threads, 32GB RAM). If your code takes less than a second for a number with a million digits, you beat all solutions which can't do that, and the tie-breaker is the time it takes for a million digit number.

To calculate the time I will randomly select 10 numbers, and look at the average time.

## Meta question

Is this a dupe? I looked for this question but couldn't find it.

I noticed that using GMP's standard I/O functions this takes 0.05 seconds for a million digit number. Is there a point to this question, or is it likely GMP is optimized enough that this will be the winning solution?

Comment: Will the program be reset between calls or is it allowed to reuse temporary values (e.g powers of 10) computed in the first call for the other 9 calls

Comment: @bsoelch I'd say it's reset between calls, although allowing precomputation somehow might be good? I'm not sure what would be more interesting.

Comment: On my computer `time python3 -c 'bin(int("1"*1000000))'` executes for 4 seconds

Comment: About GMP: You could ban third party libraries. At least in Python the standard library version of string to int is not the fastest possible solution (I tried a relatively simple recursive approach and managed to get the time for 1000000 digits from over 4 seconds to below one second).

Comment: Bad news: Python is probably getting an impl that can convert 4,000,000-digit numbers in 0.3s. It is already available as a 3rd party lib. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90716#issuecomment-1717742073

Comment: Also there is very little point in banning 3rd party libs, as you can always copy the entire code to submit it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

#### Given A Binary String, Determine Which Of Certain Substrings Are Equal And Opposite

yea the title is going to need some work

#### Concept

Take an even length binary string

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Between each bit, place an arrow

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Next, find each substring centered on each arrow which includes either/both the start and the end of the string

```
1 1
 ^
1 1 0 1
   ^
1 1 0 1 0 0
     ^
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
       ^
    0 1 0 0 1 0
         ^
        0 0 1 0
           ^
            1 0
             ^
```

If each half of the binary string has all of the flipped bits of the other half (in any order), replace the arrow with a 1, else a 0

```
1 1
 0
1 1 0 1
   0
1 1 0 1 0 0
     1
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
       1
    0 1 0 0 1 0
         0
        0 0 1 0
           0
            1 0
             1
```

Then get rid of the sublists which will leave you with just the arrows-turned-bits

```
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

You must output those bits.

#### Examples:

```
00 0
01 1
10 1
11 0
0000 000
0001 001
0011 010
1001 111
1011 100
1100 010
000011 00010
100101 11111
101101 10001
00110011 0101010
00111100 0101010
10101010 1111111
11000101 0111011
11010010 0011001
11100010 0011101
```

#### Meta

yea I don't have the vocabulary for this. I'm gonna hammer at it some more but if you read this and something jumps out at you where youre like "oh i know what thats called" Please let me know thank you

Comment: What does "opposite digits" mean?

Comment: @Someone im not sure how to phrase it, but if you have X `1`s and Y `0`s on one end, you need to have Y `1`s and X `0`s on the other side.

Comment: So order doesn't matter?

Comment: @Someone exactly. Would tacking "in any order" onto it fix that, or would you suggest a full rephrasing? EDIT: actually tried something out here, any better or still off?

Comment: It's good—I was just making sure. I think the examples explain it well enough.

Comment: (1) For your example `11010010`, the answer should be `0011001`, shouldn't it? (2) Can I rephrase the task to »For each position to break the string into two, starting from the left, place a `1` if the number of `0` digits on the shorter part is equal to the number of `1` digits among the neighboring substring of the same length on the other side, otherwise, put a `0`.«?

Comment: @Philippos (1) Yes, typo, corrected, thanks! (2) Yes! Can I include that wording / a version of it? that seems like the way to go as far as making this more explicit/formally stated... Thanks :-)

Comment: (1) The same typo is in the final line of the demonstrated example; I'm sorry I can't correct it myself. (2) Of course you can, maybe with some more words to make it more comprehendable.

Comment: @Philippos (1) lmao how did i miss that twice, thanks (2) Thank you, I'll keep working on it based on your suggestion :-)

Comment: If you want to thank me, please comment on [my idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26059/72726). someone downvoted, but did not write why.

Answer (score 1):

## Barbrack

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a non-negative integer (in decimal or any other convenient base for your language) and output a number in the numbering system **Barbrack**.

### What's that?

Barbrack is a numbering system I made up that can represent non-negative integers. Zero is represented with an empty string or an underscore, one is represented with [], and all other positive integers can be represented with a **brack**.

A **brack** is delimited with brackets [] and works as follows (with an example of 84):

1. Take your number a and find its prime factorization. In this case, the prime factorization of 84 is 2<sup>2</sup>*3<sup>1</sup>(*5<sup>0</sup>)*7<sup>1</sup>.
2. Find the indices of these primes, where the index of 2 is 1. In this case, the index of 3 is 2, since it's the prime right after 2, and the index of 7 is 4, since it's the fourth prime.
3. Take the exponents of each prime, and put them in brackets in increasing order of the size of the prime, with consecutive exponents being separated by bars (|). So the general format is [exponent of 2|exponent of 3|exponent of 5…]—in this case, [2|1|0|1]. **Minimize the number of cells!**
4. Recursively calculate the exponents in Barbrack, remembering that 0 is the empty string and 1 is []. So [2|1|0|1] => [[1]|[]||[]] => [[[]]|[]||[]].
5. Output the final result.

### Test inputs

```
0 -> (nothing)
1 -> []
2 -> [[]]
5 -> [||[]]
45 -> [|[[]]|[]]
84 -> [[[]]|[]||[]]
65535 -> [|[]|[]||||[](48 bars)[]]
65536 -> [[[[[]]]]]
```

(sidenote: (48 bars) means 48 consecutive bars in the actual output)

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- No input in Barbrack! This isn't a cat challenge!

### Scoring

Minimum bytes on a per-language basis.

Comment: Can characters other than `[|]` be used?

Comment: No, actually. I would allow other symbols, but I'm trying to stay true to my own base. (Let me guess, angle brackets for Vyxal?)

Comment: @Someone It's generally preferred to be flexible with the output format. There's no reason for those characters specifically to be used, as far as I can tell. In fact, instead of strings, you could allow nested lists too (unless I'm reading the challenge wrong)

Comment: similar challenges: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139034/encode-an-integer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254870/base-neutral-numbering-system

Comment: Yeah, the /10 bonus was definitely imbalanced.

Comment: [Input validation is generally discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/92727). Is there a particular reason you want it? How would it even work if I write a function which takes `unsigned int` as input?

Comment: Fair point. The rule was basically just "undefined behavior" but dumber anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Generate Conway's Atomic Elements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265720/generate-conways-atomic-elements)

Answer (score 1):

## [Implement the RegPack decompressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265725/implement-the-regpack-decompressor)

Answer (score 1):

## Factorial Numbers

Write a function or program to print "factorial numbers" as defined in this [xkcd comic](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2835:_Factorial_Numbers). Test cases are conveniently provided by the comic too.

You will take an integer number N as input.

You can either

1. output the factorial number representation of N
2. output the factorial number representation of all numbers up to and including N in order (note: must include N; this is different from default rules)

You can assume that the input is not "illegal", but your program must work for all legal inputs. Default loopholes and I/O rules apply. If this can be done in 1 built-in method, you may post it but it will not compete.

This is code-golf so shortest wins. The competition will be between each language, so non-golfing languages should compete.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/convert-to-and-from-the-factorial-number-system)

Comment: @emanresuA ah wow. But the post is 10 years old and the newest answer is 5 years old. Perhaps there are innovations in golfing languages that make this interesting again. What can be done about this? The comic was posted yesterday too. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the thing about good challenge ideas is that a lot of them have already been done. If you wanted to raise interest in that challenge you could post an answer to it.

Comment: Thanks. I might try that.

Answer (score 1):

## Golf my code

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

For this challenge, I'll use edit histories of answers to create a dataset of answers that have been golfed. Your task will be to write a program/function that, given a submission that was golfed in the future, will attempt to golf the submission.

You may choose the language, out of a set I'll choose based on the quantity and quality of data available, that your inputs will be in. You may choose to take inputs from multiple languages, which will not be differentiated (e.g., you can choose to score your answer over a combined Python + Jelly dataset).

The first part of your score will be the sum of bytes golfed by your program for each input, with any submissions that don't become shorter (including becoming longer) or become invalid having no impact on your score (might change this later, since otherwise you have no reason not to use a dataset of all languages).

Your final score will be your score, minus the number of bytes in your program. So, if you golf a total of 1920 bytes off the Python answers dataset, with 1080 bytes of code, your final score will be 840. Higher scores are better.

Comment: I get the idea that the program is supposed to golf answers in a specific language, but I don't understand how we're expected to do that and programmatically return correct golfed answers, please add an example

Comment: On top of the problem of validation, I feel like this has some problems depending on the languages you pick. Definitely don't include unary.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forward foo, reverse bar, but avoid dead code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269006/72726)

Comment: Trying to count "dead bytes" is a bad idea. Consider [this Pyth program](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XyktP19JQSkpsUjp/38A). The string `"rab"` is interpreted and the interpreted code is even executed but since the output is suppressed it does nothing observable. This makes it extremely difficult to determine what dead code is (only made worse by not counting unexecuted code), which will almost certainly result in this being closed.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman This is obviously no dead code. This may make things boring for some languages, but the idea is to bring up creative solutions in other languages.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I found a better definition of »dead code«, that takes in account your example.

Comment: That is better, but what does "most other characters" mean? I think you would want to say "any other byte", but that will make languages that refuse to interpret certain bytes unable to have any dead code (which doesn't seem like what you want).

Comment: You got me right. Even in the python or shell examples, no one shall argue, that replacing the comment characters by a newline will change the behaviour. But there is no doubt that you can replace those by *most* characters without anything happens. I don't want to give an exact definition of »most«. This is not legislation, it's about giving the direction of thinking, where the spirit of the challenge (and hopefully the fun) can be found.

Comment: I think this is code-challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Is it a stable structure? [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

In this challenge, a structure is a combination of row of `----` and columns of `|`, such that all rows are above at least one column and all columns are on top of either a row or the ground. Additionally, a structure must have all its component rows or columns connected vertically.

For example, the following are structures:

```
          ---      -----      -----
     |     |        |  |      | | |
|    ---   |----    -- -----  |---|
|     |    |   |    |  |   |  | | |
```

And the following are not:

```
|             |                     |
     --    ---|   ---- ---          |-----
|   |  |    | |   |      |     ---  || |
```

The last two are not structures because, although they satisfy all the other rules, they contain multiple vertically connected parts - specifically, the end of a `-` cannot connect with the side of a `|`.

A single row of `-`s can have multiple `|`s under it. That row is *stable* if the center of the row occurs within the span of the `|`s. For example, take this row:

```
---X---
 |  ||
```

The center of that row is the position marked X, and as this falls within the outer two `|`, the row is stable.

```
---XX---     ---XX---
   |||          |
```

You can also have rows with even length, in which case both central positions have to fall within the span of the columns. The first example here is stable, the second is not.

```
---X---
   |
```

Rows can even be balanced on a single `|` as long as their center is on that `|`.

A structure is stable if every row of `----` in it is stable by the above criteria.

Your challenge is to, given a valid ascii-art structure by the criterion above, determine whether it is stable or not.

Output may either be truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed) or outputting two distinct values for truthy/falsy.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

Truthy

```
|

-
|

---
| |

  ---
  | |
--- ---
 ||  |

-----
 | ||
 |---
 | |

|
---------
 | |    |


   -------
   |  |
  ------
  | |  |
-----  |
|  |   |
```

Falsy

```
--
|

--------
   |

------
| |
------
 |  |

  ---
    |
---------
    |


------------------
 | | |

-------------
|           |
------ ------
|           |
```

Answer (score 1):

## Compile Japt to JavaScript

## *this is a work in progress challenge! the spec is not finished*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parser)

[Japt] is a programming language designed by [@ETHProductions] in 2017 designed as a code-golf version of JavaScript (from which its name is derived; **Ja**vaScri**pt** → Japt). Code written in Japt is compiled to JS code. This challenge is about code-golfing that compilation process.

For this challenge, we will be using a slightly simplified version of Japt that does not support compressed string literals, shortcuts, or `ß` for recursion. This version of Japt also lacks [the semi-famous bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118064/108687) that unterminated array literals make the parser break.

### Japt syntax

Japt programs consist of a series of chained function calls (like the JavaScript `something.a(1).b(2).c(3)`). In Japt, these are written as follows:

```
a1 b2 c3
```

Each lowercase letter tells the parser to start reading arguments, and each space tells it to stop and call the function with those arguments. Here's what passing multiple arguments to functions looks like:

```
a1,2 b3,4,5 c6
```

Japt programs don't just consist of lowercase letters, digits, and spaces. Japt has syntax for four kinds of literals:

1. Numbers, like `1234` or `1.23` or `0.7`
2. Strings, like `"abcd"` or `"player 1 has {U} points"` (interpolation)
3. Arrays, like `[1,2,3]` or `[1,"a",["b","c",[2]],"d"]`
4. Functions, like `X{X+1}` or `XYZ{XaY b5 +Z}` (uppercase letters are parameter names, brackets surround function body)

An expression is made of one of the above literals, followed by any number (including zero) of chained function calls.

Note that, when the either the program ends or the parser hits a newline, any unfinished literal or function call is automatically closed:

```
mX{Xa"bcd
```

can still be parsed as calling `m` with a function that takes `X` and calls `a` on it with argument `"bcd"`, even though many structures are not fully

### Compilation to JavaScript

Japt expressions translate pretty much one-to-one with JavaScript expressions. Many expressions can be translated slightly differently and have the same results, so for this challenge, any output that is equivalent to the JavaScript expression as explained here is OK output. For example, for `a1 b2 c3` you may choose to output `U.a(1).b(2).c(3)` or you might output `U.a(1 ).b((2)).c(3 )` or similar.

If a number literal is the first part of a chained function call, it must be either surrounded in parentheses (`1.5` becomes `(1.5)`) or have a trailing space (`1.5` ). Your submission may choose either of these. You may also choose to have all numbers follow one of these conventions, not only

### Test cases

```
Japt:
a1 b2 c3
JavaScript:
U.a(1).b(2).c(3)

Japt:
a1b2c3 d4  e5
JavaScript:
U.a(1 .b(2 .c(3).d(4)).e(5)

Japt:
q| mZ{ùT+=Zl} ú mZ{Z+S+V
JavaScript:
U.q("I").m((Z)=>Z.ù(T+=Z.l())).ù().m((Z)=>Z+S+V)

Japt:
1 +2 +3 +4
JavaScript:
(((1)+2)+3)+4
```

Answer (score 1):

[Moved to the main site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266223/find-the-conflict-free-sitting-arrangement)

Comment: I'd recommend not having a fixed message required for the case where no order is possible -- AFAIK, the way it's usually done in code golf challenges is to allow the golfer to pick any distinct symbol to output. (Also, of the two options given, there is absolutely no way that any golfer would choose to output the full sentence instead of the empty string.)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Of course not! This was just meant to be a funny side mark, maybe drawing some other jokes in the answers. But I can omit it if it confuses.

Answer (score 1):

## Pushing Penguins on an Integer Iceberg

An iceberg is represented by a rectangular grid of cells. Each cell can hold one of three penguins. Penguins can be pushed in any free orthogonal direction, but they slide until they reach the edge of the grid or would bump into another penguin. Example:

```
.........
.1.....2.
....3....
.........
```

If you push each penguin in turn to the right, they will end up in the following positions:

```
.........
......1.2
........3
.........
```

Given an initial position and a target cell, your challenge is to push any of the penguins so that it comes to rest in that cell.

You can take the initial position as an iceberg size and list of penguin coordinates, or as an iceberg array of bytes, with one value for the empty cells and one or three distinct values for the penguins. In the latter case the target cell can have its own distinct value or it can be a coordinate. (Although the input can only be bytes the type of the array can be larger.)

The output list of pushes should identify the penguin to be pushed, either by its initial index or its current position, and either the direction (which can be encoded as any four convenient byte values) or target of the push, or if the penguins have three distinct values then it can be a list of updated iceberg arrays each with one penguin having been pushed to a new position from the previous. (The initial position does not have to be included in the output.)

You can assume that the target cell will be in the interior of the iceberg as the edge cells are trivial as they only require two penguins to solve. (And the corner cells are even more trivial as they only require one penguin.)

Your doesn't have to output an optimal solution but it must be deterministic. One approach is to devise a systematic solution that solves every cell on the iceberg but only output as far as the target cell.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 1):

## Print the banned characters based on the most common characters [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

This is an [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) post, so in this challenge every answer (except the first answer) depends on the previous answer.

The goal of this challenge is to output the restricted characters based on the most common `n` characters, if happens to be a tie, then the characters with the lowest UTF-8 range is banned

The max bytes for every answer is:

\begin{align}2n+60\end{align}

where `n` is answer number

### Rules

- The answers only output the restricted characters, no newlines, no other characters like that.

  - The code may output the restricted characters once, in any order.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.
- No answerer may answer twice in a row.
- No languages may used in the last 5 answers (Or any answer if there are less than 5 answers).
- Every answer takes empty or no input, and outputs to STDOUT. No answer should output to STDERR.
- The wrong answers (that break rules or don't do that this challenge say) are completely ignored if this answer is 10 minutes old, and should be deleted.

### Scoring

The lowest score is the best. Using this formula:

\begin{align}\frac{b+1}{n+1}\end{align}

Where `b` is byte count and `n` is answer number, we can score the answers based on the lowest score. The answer is accepted if the challenge hasn't recieved answers for 5 days.

Tiebreaker is the earliest answer.

### Example

First answer

```
# 1: Python 3

    print(end="")

Character uses:

    ": 2 (Banned)
    n: 2
    (: 1
    ): 1
    =: 1
    e: 1
    i: 1
    p: 1
    r: 1
    t: 1
```

The second answer should output `"`. If the second answer's code is `ppaaa`, then the third answer should output either `pa` or `ap` (because you should output two restricted characters), and doesn't use these characters.

Note: The scoring formula is based on the byte count and the answer number. The goal is to output the restricted characters efficiently while adhering to the specified byte limits.

Have a great day!

Comment: What should clarify that codes can't use restricted characters (at least I'm assuming they can't). In the example, if the second answer was `ppaaa`, would the third one have to output `p` and `a`?

Comment: @CommandMaster If the first answer is `print(end="")`, and the second answer is `ppaaa` then the third answer have to output `p` and `a`, so you're right.

Answer (score 1):

**Challenge - Find the nearest "well known" fraction**

Find the nearest useful, well-known fraction for any decimal.

Here I'm defining well-known fractions as

- 1/2s - everyone can get on board with halves
- 1/3s - similarly easy to picture
- 1/4s - slicing up a pizza for greedy people
- 1/5s - at the edge of usefulness, but I think still useful
- 1/6s - only 1/6 and 5/6 are not covered by the above, but it's a pizza slice so just sneaks in

BUT NOT

- 1/7s - no-one uses sevenths
- 1/8s and 1/9s - might as well just go to    decimals now

Thus, the challenge is, given any number between 0 and 1, output a numerator and denominator where the latter is between 1 and 6 inclusive, with a forward slash in-between, representing the nearest fraction to the decimal, from the following:

**0/1 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3 2/5 1/2 3/5 2/3 3/4 4/5 5/6 1/1**

Zero and One results can either be output as 0/1 or 0, 1/1 or 1

TIE BREAK - where a decimal is equidistant between two common fractions (e.g. 0.775 is equidistant from 4/5 and 3/4), then the LOWEST denominator wins, so an input of 0.775 outputs 3/4.

(Sandbox comment - I hope this isn't trivially easy!)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Golf! This seems like it's definitely not a trivially easy challenge.

Comment: Nice first challenge! The requirement of a slash between the numerator and denominator seems a bit annoying. Why can't answers return a pair of numbers? Regarding the tie breaker - if the input is a floating-point number, then none of the midpoints are exactly representable, which mean the tie breaker isn't relevant, which significantly disadvantages taking the input as a fraction. I'd suggest either dropping the tie breaker, or allowing only exact fractions as input. Lastly, the phrasing is a bit awkward - just "return the closest fraction with denominator as most 6" would be enough.

Comment: I was thinking of posing a similar question, except the output would be one of the Unicode vulgar fractions U+00BC-U+00BE or U+2150-215E (you would pick the nearest as before).

Comment: The other approach for tie breaking is for a given input the code should always output the same result but for the ties either output is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

## Twist words to intersect

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given three strings of alphabetic characters \$A\$, \$B\$, and \$X\$, (all uppercase or all lowercase, your choice), output an arrangement of \$A\$ and \$B\$ on a grid such that they intersect *only* at the letters of \$X\$. Each word can start at any location in the grid; after that, every character in the word must be placed in the grid at a location orthogonal (directly above, below, to the left, or to the right) of the previous character. The word must not intersect itself. The grid can be arbitrarily large.

For example, if \$A\$ was `ASHAMEFULACT`, \$B\$ was `CHARACTER`, and \$X\$ was `HAT`, one possible arrangement is shown below.

[image]

In text format:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ a m e f _
_ c H a r u _
_ a s c A l _
_ _ e T c _ _
_ _ r _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

(The places where the words intersect are shown in capitals; the rest of the letters are shown in lowercase.)

You can output in any reasonable format -- the format above is not required. For example, you do not need to have the intersecting letters be a different case than the rest of the letters in the words. One possible output format would be a 2D array of characters, like

```
[ ["",  "A", "M", "E", "F"],
  ["C", "H", "A", "R", "U"],
  ["A", "S", "C", "A", "L"],
  ["",  "E", "T", "C", "" ],
  ["",  "R", "",  "",  "" ] ]
```

*You can assume that such an arrangement is possible to create -- e.g. \$A\$ and \$B\$ will both have the letters of \$A\$ as a subsequence (in order).*

Standard loopholes are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

Comment: Is the grid assumed to be of infinite size? You might want to say that somewhere. Also, I think you should recommend a specific format that might help answerers get on track, and then they can come up with golfier formats. (A matrix of characters doesn't seem complicated, but this challenge looks a bit more complicated than it is, so it might be better to state some options outright.)

Comment: @noodleman Does this address edit your concerns? Do you have a suggestion for a golf-y format to mention?

Answer (score 1):

### [Add two natural numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266688/add-two-natural-numbers)

Comment: I think it's an interesting idea, and reasonably clear -- I would phrase it differently however; these aren't exactly the rules that define addition. I would say "show a sequence of applications of these two operations to get from `a+b` to a single number representing their sum" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a Code-Golf type game for an [authorization language](https://www.osohq.com/docs/reference/polar/patterns). The premise is to review a piece of an authorization policy and the permissions to identify the least number of rules you need to create in order to keep the permissions true.

Example of one policy and two permissions below. What are Alice and Anthony's roles?

- Alice can read Organization metaworldpeace
- Anthony can add_member Organization metaworldpeace

```js
actor User { }

resource Organization { 
    roles = ["admin", "member"];
    permissions = ["read", "add_member"];
# role hierarchy:
# admins inherit all member permissions
"member" if "admin";

# org-level permissions
"read" if "member";
"add_member" if "admin";
```

Comment: ??? i cant see what this has to do with code golf

Comment: @Seggan It's underspecified, but does seem like an [tag:atomic-code-golf].

Comment: Or perhaps a metagolf...?

Answer (score 1):

## Can I do this parkour?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

In this challenge, you'll be given a list of platforms (line segments), a start point, a goal point, and your acceleration, stopping, and jump strength. Your task will be to determine whether it's possible to make it from the start point to the goal point by running and jumping on the given platforms.

### Physics

I can be modelled as a point, subject to gravity. All positions will be given in meters, and gravity can be assumed to accelerate me downward at \$10\:\mathrm{m/s^2}\$. If I'm standing on a horizontal platform, I can accelerate in a direction I'm moving in (or if I'm at \$0\:\mathrm{m/s}\$) at a rate of \$a\:\mathrm{m/s^2}\$, where \$a\$ is the acceleration taken as input.

(unfinished)

Comment: Even though it's unfinished, I'll leave some thoughts: (1) Should time be treated as continuous or discrete (i.e. can you change your acceleration at any time \$t \in \mathbb{R}\$ or just at \$t=0,1,\ldots\$)? (2) Are the platforms all the same size, or can they vary in width (I'm assuming they can vary in position)? (3) It might be nicer if you have the acceleration be 1 m/s^2 (or 1 in whatever units you're using).

Comment: (4) I'm not quite sure what "I can accelerate in the direction I'm moving in" means; does that mean if your current velocity is positive in the x axis, you can only accelerate in the positive x direction, or can you also decelerate in that direction? Does this only apply to the x (horizontal) axis, or does it include the y as well?

Comment: @97.100.97.109 1. Time is continuous 2. The platforms can be arbitrary line segments on a vertical 2d plane, so yes, any length 3. Maybe I'll change acceleration to be a constant yeah 4. Deceleration has a separate speed

Comment: I'm thinking I'll remove the separate deceleration speed, probably unnecessary complexity

Comment: Oh sorry, I realized I misspoke -- for (3) I was referring to making the acceleration due to gravity have a unit acceleration (1 m/s^2), not the "player's" acceleration.

Comment: Also, the line segments can have arbitrary x and y positions and lengths? If so, then this question seems like it's basically asking the solvers to write a 2D physics engine, which seems a little bit too much. (I was assuming the platforms were restricted to \$y=0\$.)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Yes, they can have arbitrary positions

Answer (score 1):

posted: [Convert real numbers between factoradic and positive integer bases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267096/119818)

Answer (score 1):

## [Write the date in abbreviated Latin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267257/write-the-date-in-abbreviated-latin)

Comment: If 01/03 is 3 day delay then why 01/04 is not 2 day delay?

Comment: Is `Kal Iul` intended if others are `Jul`?

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks! They were all supposed to be Iul. I don't know how I typoed all these Jul in there. It's fixed now.

Comment: @l4m2 Because 01/04 is the day just before Non Ian, so it's `prid Non Ian`. If you look at the second bullet-point in the three bullet points at the beginning of "How to write dates": *"A date which is just before a special day is encoded by writing `prid` followed by the name of that special day;"* Which is why we only ever need roman numerals between 3 and 19; we never need 2.

Comment: I added this paragraph suggested by the author of the original latin.stackexchange post: "The Roman counting system is oddly inclusive to modern taste. Whenever we would say that something is n days earlier, the Romans would have said n+1. The day just before the special day is two days before it (we'd say one day) and uses `prid` instead of numbering, so the unnamed days start their numbering at 3."

Comment: `Mai` missing in places

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Prefix-Suffix equality, part 1

Given an array of two distinct byte-sized values, please perform the following operations or their equivalent:

- Construct an array of its nontrival prefixes and suffixes, starting with the array itself and working down to its first and last elements.
- Compare each element of the two arrays elementwise, with the result `1` if the two elements are identical and `0` if they are not.
- Taking the array of `1`s and `0`s, interpret that as a number in base `2`.
- Double this number.

The result turns out to be the expected number of uniformly random selections between your original two values to get the input array.

Example using `H` and `T` as the two byte-sized values:

```
HTTHT  HTTHT   1
HTTH    TTHT   0
HTT      THT   0
HT        HT   1
H          T   0
```

Converting `10010` to decimal gives `18`, which is then doubled to give the final result of `36`. This is the expected number of coin tosses to produce the pattern `HTTHT`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 1):

## Deja vu

Given two arrays, let's call them a and b, and a number n, your task is to see if there exists a subarray in a so that that subarray's sum is n and there is a subarray in b that also sums to n and has the same length. You may assume that all elements in a and b are positive integers, and so is n.

For example, if a is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, b is `[2, 2 ,2, 6, 7]` and n is 6, the output would be truthy because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 in a and 2 + 2 + 2 = 6 in b.

## Test cases

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [2, 2, 2, 6, 7], 6 => True
[] [] 0 => True
```

Shortest code wins!

---

- More test cases coming soon
- Not sure if Deja vu is a good title or not

Answer (score 1):

### Challenge

Create a sorting algorithm in as few bytes as possible. It can be, at worst, \$ O(n^2) \$. This can be insertion sort, mergesort, quicksort, or any other sorting algorithm with \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity.

### Input

An array of numbers, such as `[1,2,3]` or `[41,17,8]`.

### Output

You can print an array of numbers in order, or you can print them (ordered) one by one. Sorting `[3,1,2]` could return:

`[1,2,3]`

or

```
1
2
3
```

### Rules

- Program must run in \$ O(n^2) \$ time or better
- The program cannot use any sorting functions, libraries, etc. You can, however create a function that sorts, but it must be made from scratch in your program.

### Test cases

```
[0,1,2,3] -> [0,1,2,3]

[5,2,8,91,4,6] -> [2,4,5,6,8,91]

[16,42,13,2,71] -> [2,13,16,42,71]
```

Comment: What exactly counts as a predefined function (I guess predefined *sorting* function, but still)? APL and its descendant languages don't have "sort"; instead, they use "grade" (given an array `A`, calculates `[x, y, z, ...]` such that `[A[x], A[y], A[z]...] == sorted(A)`) to implement sorting.

Comment: Also check out the comments under [this related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75973/78410), especially the "can I use X?" ones.

Comment: @Bubbler thank you for the response! I'll make sure to specify that it must be built from scratch and cannot use any sorting functions, libraries, etc.

Comment: "Built from scratch" is still ambiguous in today's standards. Can I use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)? [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)? [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)? [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition)? [`select_nth_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.select_nth_unstable)?

Comment: @Bubbler It's really hard to define. Do you have a better way to phrase it?

Comment: No, and that's why [Do X Without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/78410) type of challenges are not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

## [Auto-golf an esolang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267439/72726)

Comment: It's pretty easy to prove; just find code for 0 through 5 and you can get anything else from `+` spam. (Having all of those in the test cases might be nice.) Also maybe note the initial value of the accumulator outside of just a command specification. Possibly even consider cutting `!` entirely in favor of a single implicit output so partitioning the digits doesn't detract from finding the right sequence of `+~`, but the limited range might make some answers more interesting anyways.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thank you for your input. But that proof is boring, isn't it? (-; I added the additional examples and the initial accumulator value. I believe, the possibilities given by partitioning will make this more interesting. And there are still enough numbers like 805 with a winning solution without partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

## Pi to n digits

Calculate \$π\$ to n digits - no overshooting. The input will be a positive integer or 0. Your program should output \$π\$ displayed with *exactly* n digits (not counting '3.'). You cannot use any function that uses or returns pi under the hood. Standard loopholes are not allowed.

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Does this have to work with arbitrarily large values of `n` if supported by the language? e.g. does a Python answer have to work for n=99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999989999999999?

Comment: This seems like a dupe of [Calculate 500 digits of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/506/calculate-500-digits-of-pi), requiring the number of digits to be variable wouldn't affect answers interestingly in my opinion.

Comment: @Somebody It only has to work up to the largest number type supported by the language.

Answer (score 1):

**Is your license plate Tetris-compliant?**

Write a program that outputs a truthy value if the letters in its input are only letters that name Tetris pieces (I, J, L, O, S, T, Z), and a falsy value if otherwise.

Input: A string. You can assume it is either empty, or contains only numbers, letters in a case of your choice, and spaces.

Output: A truthy value (printing `true` or `1` to the console is fine) if there are no letters in the input, OR if all the letters are from the set `{I, J, L, O, S, T, Z}`

Objective: Code golf, so lowest score wins! Standard per-language scoring rules apply, so bytes for C#/Java/etc., codels for Piet, and so forth.

Test cases:

```
"" => true
"1234" => true
"123 TOL" => true
"9584K94LSZ" => false
"HELLO WORLD" => false
"LLO OL" => true
"876 TSL 234 IOT" => true,
"123 tol" => true
" " => true
```

Reference function:

```csharp
public static bool IsTetrisCompliant(string s)
{
    var tetrisLetters = new[] { 'i', 'o', 't', 's', 'z', 'j', 'l' };
    var letters = s.ToLowerInvariant().Where(c => char.IsLetter(c));
    return letters.All(l => tetrisLetters.Contains(l));
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## Optimal infinite monkeys: output Shakespeare with the highest probability

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

This challenge is something of a sequel to [Write Moby Dick, approximately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately), but the mechanics and scoring system are quite different, and I expect it to lead to quite a different challenge.

We all know that a monkey hammering out random bytes will output the works of Shakespeare with some probability. This probability is extremely low.

But what if the monkey would type out a computer program instead, and then we run the computer program and see if *that* outputs the works of Shakespeare? The program might itself behave randomly, but in such a way that the probability of outputting Shakespeare is much higher overall.

The essence of this challenge is to maximise the following probability:

```
p(the monkey outputs your program) * p(your program outputs the works of Shakespeare)
```

To make that work as a practical challenge we will have to fake the randomness. Your program will not really behave randomly but will output probabilities instead, so that we can calculate the probability that your program outputs the works of Shakespeare, even if that probability is astronomically low.

### more details

The following file contains the complete works of Shakespeare in ASCII format. **[to do: create the file and upload it somewhere]**

Your program is meant to represent a random process that *might* output the works of Shakespeare with some probability. But depending on how your program works that probability might be so low that it would never practically happen. So instead of using a random number generator, every time your program would output a letter it will output a probability distribution instead. Another program will keep track of the total probability.

It works like this: your program (or function etc.) will be called multiple times (about 3,500,000 times). On each invocation it will be given the first *n* characters of `shakespeare.txt`. Its output will be a probability distribution over ASCII characters, which is its probability of guessing a given next character. This output can be in any reasonable format - for example, it could be a Python array of 128 floats. But it must be a probability distribution, i.e. in this example the floats must sum to 1.

The following pseudocode shows how your score is calculated:

```
log_p_monkey_outputs_program = -(size of your submission in bytes)*8

log_p_program_outputs_shakespeare = 0
target_text = contents of shakespeare.txt
for n = 1 to length(target_text)-1
    probabilities = your_program(first n characters of target_text)
    correct_prob = probabilities[(n+1)th character of target_text]
    log_p_program_outputs_shakespeare += log2(correct_prob)

score = log_p_monkey_outputs_program + log_p_program_outputs_shakespeare
```

The score that this program calculates is the logarithm of the probability that the monkey outputs your program and your program then outputs Shakespeare, assuming that we always feed the program's output back in as input. We calculate the logarithm to avoid floating point errors, as the final probability will be extremely small.

Note that the logarithm is to base 2. If your language doesn't provide the `log2` function you should use `log(correct_prob)/log(2)`.

If the scoring program is implemented correctly, the score will always be negative. A higher score (closer to 0) is better.

Note that your program outputs a probability distribution but it should not itself behave randomly. Your program **may not** use a random number generator - it must always return the same probability distribution for a given input.

If you want to store state in between invocations this is allowed. You can do this by writing to an external file, by using `static` or global variables, by submitting a class rather than a function, using a state monad, or whatever else works for your language.

### Submission format

Your submission should include the following, which **do** count towards the size of your submission. If they are excessively large you can link to github etc.

- your program
- any data it needs in order to run

Your submission should also include the following, which **don't** count towards its size:

- the code used to calculate its score, implementing the pseudocode above (this doesn't need to be in the same language as your submission). Please don't golf this.
- any code that was used to generate your submission (e.g. to create any data files that you included)
- an explanation of how your submission works.

### Rules

As mentioned, your program must run deterministically, so that it always outputs the same probability distribution given the same input (and hence always gets the same score).

If at any time the value of `correct_prob` in the scoring pseudocode is 0, then your score is -∞, which is the worst possible score.

You **may not** use any libraries or functions that your language might have that include data or statistics about natural language. This includes pre-trained neural networks, word lists, etc. It also includes any built-in function that outputs any of Shakespeare's works. It's fine to use neural networks and word lists etc., but the data or weights must be included in your submission and count towards its byte count.

You **may not** use any libraries or functions designed for compressing or decompressing data. It's fine to use algorithms like bzip etc., but you have to implement them yourself (and hence include the implementation in your byte count).

If you want to store state between invocations you can do this however you like, as long as your program never has access to 'future' bytes from the `shakespeare.txt` file. (So, for example, you can't just pass it a string containing all of the input and get back a big list of probability distributions as output.)

You must actually run your test program and calculate/verify your score before submitting your entry. If your submission runs too slowly for you to verify its score then it is not qualified to compete, even if you know what its score would be in principle.

You may import existing libraries other than the exceptions above, but you may not load any other external files unless they're included in your byte count. Your code may not access the `shakespeare.txt` file in any way other than described above.

## A note about the scoring system

In the sandbox, several people had an intuition that the optimal answers to this challenge will take the form of compressing the `shakespeare.txt` file and outputting it deterministically. However, the scoring system has been carefully chosen so that this strategy will not be optimal. If you have a stochastic solution then in theory you can turn it into a perfect deterministic solution, at the cost of adding `-log2(p(program outputs shakespeare))` bits of code into your program. This extra code decreases `p(monkey outputs program)` by exactly the same factor that it increases `p(program outputs shakespeare)`, resulting in zero change to the overall score.

But this is the absolute best you can do. Any real encoding will be less than perfect, so in reality the net result of such a strategy will be to slightly decrease the score. Because of this, it's likely that the most competitive answers will be stochastic. However, deterministic, compression-based answers are permitted and are welcome to complete, as long as they meet the spec.

---

*sandbox notes:*

*On the off chance that I'm wrong about the properties of the scoring system, I intend to battle-test this challenge before I post it. To do this I will implement (i) the obvious illegal solution using bzip2 to compress the whole text, and (ii) the not-quite-so-obvious illegal solution using bzip2 to stochastically predict the next character from the ones already received, without including a compressed version of the text in the code. I expect solution (ii) to beat solution (i), for the reasons described in the last section of the question. If it doesn't I will either give up on the challenge or add a fudge factor into the scoring system to give slightly more reward to stochastic solutions.*

*I'll also post a sample answer (legal but not very competitive), in order to address the point about the spec being a bit daunting to understand.*

*I'm unsure about the rule banning built-in compression algorithms. It seems more elegant to leave it out, and it *would* still be a meaningful challenge without that rule. But in [Paint Starry Night, objectively, in 1kB of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) off-the-shelf compression spoiled the fun a bit, and I'm worried that with this scoring system the same could happen here. I'm happy to hear any thoughts about that.*

*I'd also really like feedback on the score calculation pseudocode - is it sufficiently clear how the score is calculated, and can I make it clearer?*

*Finally, a very specific query: the ban on word tables seems like it would rule out some golfing languages. I don't want to rule out any languages but don't want to open the floodgates either, so if someone can think of a good middle ground it would be helpful.*

Comment: I'd say you can encode randomness into program, resulting in a pure "output Shakespeare shortest code"

Comment: @l4m2 if I understand correctly that would just make it a [tag:kolmogorov-complexty] challenge. This is meant to be more of an optimisation challenge like [Paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) or [Write Moby Dick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately). I like Kolmogorov complexity challenges but these optimisation type challenges are quite different in terms of what makes a good answer, and that's what I'm going for with this question.

Comment: @l4m2 ah - or maybe you're saying that the optimal solution will be to compress the shakespeare file and just output it deterministically? If so that's a reasonable criticism but having done the maths I'm more or less certain it's not the case.

Comment: The point is that compressing the file in this way produces an optimal `p_program_outputs_shakespeare` but you have to include all the data in compressed form in the program, so you pay for it in `p_monkey_outputs_program`. If you can do some kind of lossy compression then you'll do worse at `p_program_outputs_shakespeare` but should be able to save more on `p_monkey_outputs_program`. So I expect the optimum to be some combination of compression and probabilistic guessing.

Comment: Basically, if I'm right, the optimal solution should be to implement a learning algorithm with good inductive biases - something that doesn't contain much specific information about Shakespeare (hence doesn't take up much space and does well on `p_monkey_outputs_program`) but is good at learning patterns in the text, so that it gets better at predicting it over time and scores well on `p_program_outputs_shakespeare`. I could be wrong, but I've been thinking about this for a very long time and if I am wrong I don't think it will be for a trivial reason.

Comment: But what is fed to learn?

Comment: @l4m2 on each time step it gets fed the first *n* bytes and has to predict the *(n+1)* th one. So by the time it's guessing the millionth byte it's had a megabyte of data to learn from.

Comment: I will check I'm right - before I post this I will implement the obvious compression-based solution using bzip etc. and see if I can beat it with stochastic guessing. If I can't then your worry is correct and I will have to change the scoring system.

Comment: Come on people: *comment on how the challenge can be improved* or *say why you think it's not suitable for this site*. Just downvoting the sandbox answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I don't understand the two downvotes personally; I'd ignore them. It might need some work, I haven't read it thoroughly enough to think of any possible issues, but it certainly seems like a cool concept

Comment: not use a random number generator = deterministic program

Comment: @WD that's right, yes - the program has to be deterministic, because we fake the randomness in order to be able to calculate the score. If this isn't clear please let me know and I will do my best to improve it.

Comment: Challenge seems good, but also a bit daunting/confusing - a sample [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]-esque answer could help serve as a 'template' for what kind of inputs/outputs you should program

Comment: I don't think this is meaningfully different from kolomogorov complexity - given a solution to this challenge, using arithmetic coding you can get an answer which outputs Shakespeare exactly, and is only a little bit longer (assuming you can encoding raw data at almost-full efficiency). On the other hand, an answer which outputs Shakespeare exactly trivially gives a solution to this challenge

Comment: @CommandMaster I don't think it's necessarily true that it will be only a little bit longer. Assuming optimal coding the extra length is around `-log2(p(program outputs shakespeare))` bits. Adding those bits into your code means you increase `-log2(p(monkey outputs program))` by exactly the same amount. But (i) optimal coding is hard, and (ii) you also have to pay the cost of implementing the decoding. These two factors mean that in practice the stochastic solution is likely to be better than the deterministic one.

Comment: I've already admitted I might be wrong about that, but I intend to test it. Before posting the challenge I will implement (i) the obvious illegal solution using bzip2 to compress the whole text, and (ii) the not-quite-so-obvious illegal solution using bzip2 to stochastically predict the next character from the ones already received, without including a compressed version of the text in the code. I expect solution (ii) to beat solution (i). If it doesn't I will either give up on the challenge or add a fudge factor into the scoring system to slightly reward stochastic solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Test whether a sequence is bitonic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268592/72726)

Answer (score 1):

## [Convert to Spoken Binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268685/convert-to-spoken-binary?noredirect=1&lq=1)

## [Convert from Spoken Binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268741/convert-from-spoken-binary)

Answer (score 1):

## How many machines do I need?

In the game Planet Crafter, there is limited scope for automation. In particular, you can grow or extract materials, combine them into products, and launch them in rockets, which then trades them for Terra Tokens.

You can launch up to 25 items at once, and the trade takes 10 minutes to complete, during which time you would like to be able to craft the next 25 items. However, you can also craft multiple trading rockets. This means that you'll need more machines so that you can turn each rocket around before the next one arrives back. The special case is actually for single rocket, which takes the same time as two rockets but you need two more Auto-Crafters so that you can store the products while waiting for the rocket to return.

The following items are accepted for trade:

- Bacteria Sample. Requires 3 Algae, 3 Water. Unfortunately I don't know the production speed of Algae, but 1 Water can produced every 100 seconds.
- Iridium Rod. Requires 9 Iridium. 1 Iridium can be produced every 75 seconds.
- Osmium Rod. Requires 9 Osmium. 1 Osmium can be produced every 75 seconds.
- Super Alloy Rod. Requires 8 Super Alloy, 1 Aluminium. Both can be produced every 75 seconds.
- High Quality Food. Requires 1 Honey, 1 Beans. Unfortunately I don't know the production speed of Beans, but 1 Honey can be produced every 160 seconds.
- Fabric. Requires 2 Silk. 1 Silk can be produced every 200 seconds.
- Uranium Rod. Requires 9 Uranium. 1 Uranium can be produced every 75 seconds.
- Cookie. Unfortunately I don't know the production speed. It needs two extra Auto-Crafters.
- Rocket Engine. Requires 1 Super Alloy, 2 Uranium, 9 Iridium. Each can be produced every 75 seconds. Also requires an extra Auto-Crafter.
- Circuit Board. Requires 1 Iron, 2 Silicon, 1 Aluminium, 1 Nitrogen, 1 Water, 2 Mushroom, 1 Zeolite. Unfortunately I don't know the production speed for Mushroom. 1 Nitrogen can be produced every 80 seconds, while the others can be produced every 75 seconds. Also requires an extra Auto-Crafter.
- Pulsar Quartz. Requires 1 Zeolite, 1 Osmium, 1 Uranium, 1 Iridium, 1 Methane. 1 Methane can be produced every 80 seconds, while the others can be produced every 75 seconds.
- Fusion Energy Cell. Requires 3 Zeolite, 5 Osmium, 3 Uranium, 3 Iridium, 3 Methane, 1 Obsidian. 1 Methane can be produced every 80 seconds, while the others can be produced every 75 seconds. Also requires an extra Auto-Crafter.

Just to complicate matters, it's possible to buff your machines; each buff makes your machine 25% more efficient, so that four buffs would double the output, eight would triple it, and so on, however only 8 machines can be affected by a buff, at which point the buff is equivalent to two extra machines.

Fortunately, I am not expecting you to produce detailed recipes for each product. Instead, your program or function will be given the following data:

- The number of trading rockets you wish to supply
- The quantity required of a particular material
- The extraction speed of that material
- The number of buffs you intend to apply

Your program or function should then output the number of extraction machines required.

Example: Extracting Methane for Pulsar Quartz for 4 Trading Rockets:

- You only need 1 Auto-Crafter
- Methane takes 80 seconds each to extract.
- Because you want to turn around 3 rockets while waiting for the 4th, you want 75 Methane in 10 minutes which is 1 every 8 seconds
- You therefore need 10 extraction machines.

Example: Extracting Water for Bacteria Samples for 3 Trading Rockets, with 1 buff:

- You need 1 Auto-Crafter
- Water takes 100 seconds each to extract, but with 1 buff this reduces to 80 seconds.
- Because the recipe uses 3 Water, and you want to turn around 2 rockets while waiting for the third, you want 150 Water in 10 minutes which is 1 every 4 seconds
- You therefore need 20 extraction machines. (In practice, you would have 25 extraction machines, or 23 with 8 receiving 1 buff, or 21 with either 16 receiving 1 buff or 8 receiving 2 buffs, etc.)

Example: Extracting Zeolite for Fusion Energy Cells for 1 Trading Rocket, with 2 buffs:

- You need 4 Auto-Crafters (2 for Fusion Energy Cells and 2 for only having one Rocket)
- Zeolite takes 75 seconds each to extract, but with 2 buffs this reduces to 50 seconds.
- Because the recipe uses 3 Zeolite, you want 75 Zeolite in 10 minutes which is 1 every 8 seconds
- You therefore need 7 extraction machines.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Bonus brownie points for writing a program that takes the name of a recipe and the number of rockets and outputs the number of Auto-Crafters you need.

Answer (score 1):

## "Perfect" an array

Given an n non-negative integers, how many numbers must be changed so that each number x appears x times? You cannot add or remove elements, only replace them.

For example:

```
1 6 23 6 9 23 1 1 6
```

can be turned into:

```
1 6 2 6 6 2 6 6 6
```

with 5 changes, which is optimal.

### Test cases

```
0 => 1
1 2 3 => 1
5 5 5 5 5 => 0
23 7 4 8 => 3
100 100 100 6 => 4
```

---

  Would appreciate help checking the test cases (and the sample case)

Comment: Why is it being in a grid relevant? Couldn't it just be a flat array?

Comment: @Command Master Good point.

Answer (score 1):

## Slowest Irreducible Sorting Algorithm

*Inspired by the biggest irreducible quine and hello world challenges*

Sorting things quickly is something that has been greatly researched. However, sorting things in the slowest and most inefficient way is something you don't hear about very often. Let's change that.

Your task today is to write the slowest sorting algorithm, as measured by worst case scenario (`O` notation).

However, it needs to be optimally not-optimal - removing any steps from the algorithm should not result in a more optimal algorithm - bogosorting in a loop that runs O(n^2) times is not irreducible, as it can be done with a single bogosort.

Answer with the slowest complexity wins, tie-broken on shortest answer in bytes.

### Sandbox meta

- How could I better specify irreducibility? It's obviously not as easy as the irreducibility requirements of the byte based challenges, but there should be some method of objectively determining it.

Comment: Why can't you use byte irreducibility?

Comment: @CommandMaster I intentionally wanted to make it about the algorithm speed rather than byte count.

Comment: You can still require byte irreducibility to disallow useless code, but it does allow for some weird manipulations. Perhaps looking at minors of the AST which are themselves valid ASTs?

Answer (score 1):

## [Implement a typeface based on a 3x3 bitmap matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269076/91472)

Answer (score 1):

## Output a unique subset of the positive integers [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

Your challenge is to output an infinite subset of the positive integers. However, the subset your program outputs must be disjoint from all the subsets that the other answers output.

For example, if the first answer outputs an infinite sequence of square numbers `1,4,9,16,25...`, the sets output by all subsequent answers cannot contain any square numbers, so the second answer can't output for example the triangle numbers `1,3,6,10...` as it contains a 1. It could however output the primes `2,3,5,7,11...` as by definition primes cannot be square. A third answer could output odd powers of 10 `10, 1000, 100000,10000000...` as this is disjoint from the previous two.

To avoid answers taking up too much of the output space, the probability of a random positive integer being in your set should converge to a value less than 0.01. For example, the following sets would be fine:

- 1,2,3,5,8,13... (fibonacci numbers, chance converges to 0)
- 1,4,9,16,25... (square numbers, chance converges to 0)
- 2,3,5,7,11...  (primes, chance converges to 0?)
- 1000,2000,3000,4000... (multiples of 1000, chance converges to 0.001)

But the following would not:

- 1,4,6,8,9,10,12... (composite numbers, chance converges to 1 (?))
- 1,3,5,7,9,11... (odd numbers, chance converges to 0.5)

Your answer may not rely on unproven conjectures, and you should be able to prove that your set is infinite and disjoint from all previous answers. For example, outputting the [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) would not be allowed as it is not known whether there are infinitely many, and in the previous example outputting [the pentagonal-triangular numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalTriangularNumber.html) \$ > 1\$ as the third answer would not be allowed as it is not known whether there are any members of that sequence that are squares.

You may output an infinite sequence of integers, or take an integer \$n\$ and output the \$n\$th or first \$n\$ terms, using 0-indexing or 1-indexing.

<insert winning criteria here>

## Meta

- Should I allow taking a number and returning whether it's in the set?
- I'm not sure about the winning criterion. I want to incentivise short code and simple sequences, so the standard "last answer wins" or "second-to-last answer wins" might not work too well, but balancing anything based on code length is annoying.

Comment: 1. If your sequence is <1% of unchosen values then this can go infinitely, which seems good 2. If everyone just output p^n for prime p this would get bad. We need to at least encourage **some**one to jump out

Comment: If you want this to be non-cooperative then the score could be some function which increases with length and number of previous answers, and decreases with number of following answers. However, there's the problem of someone using a (seeded) RNG to choose the sequence, which would almost definitely require all following answers to implement that PRNG and generate the sequence to avoid colliding with it

Comment: I was gonna do all of the positive integers :(

Comment: *"2,3,5,7,11... (primes, chance converges to 0?)"* << Yes. The so-called [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says there are approximately a frequency of 1/log(n) primes up to n. This takes a very long time to fall below 1%, but it does eventually :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Validate a CPF number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269151/91472)

Answer (score 1):

## [Possible moves in Othello/Reversi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269682/possible-moves-in-othello-reversi)

Comment: This actually seems interesting, commenting since it's late and otherwise you wouldn't see

Answer (score 1):

## Is it mate in one?

Given a 8x8 chessboard, determine if white can checkmate black in one move. For this challenge, you may assume there are only 4 types of pieces:

kings (represented by a "k")

queens (represented by a "q")

rooks (represented by a "r")

and knights (represented by a "n".)

The black version of these pieces are the capital version of the white pieces. You may assume both sides start with a king, and that every position will be legal, (e. g. there won't be any positions where white can just take black's king) and white will never be in check. Squares with no pieces on them can be any char you like that is not in "kqrnKQRN". You will not have to consider short or long castles. All pieces move the same way they do in normal chess.

### An example

For example, in the following position:

```
......RK
.......Q
........
......nq
.........
.........
.........
k.......
```

White can play the move Qxh7, checkmate.

---

- I have not tried this myself.
- Any suggestions or/for test cases?

Comment: Very related- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/190898/108687 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3229/108687

Comment: I feel like determing if it's checkmate and finding checkmate are very different. As for the second one, I think I'll try to make the challenge more unique.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Aircraft registration numbers

Write a program that takes a United States aircraft registration number and returns a 24-bit ICAO hex code corresponding to that registration and vice-versa.

An aircraft registration number always begins with an N and is followed by 1 to 5 characters: 1 to 5 digits and then 0 to 2 letters. That is, one of the following three patterns:

- N plus 1 to 5 digits
- N plus 1 to 4 digits then one letter
- N plus 1 to 3 digits then two letters

The first digit cannot be 0 and the letters I and O are not used. The letters always follow the digits.

ICAO hex codes assigned to the US are numbers from A00001 to ADF7C7 (in hexadecimal). They are assigned in alphanumeric order: A00001 corresponds to N1, A00002 corresponds to N1A, A00003 to N1AA, A00004 to N1AB, etc., up to ADF7C7 for N99999.

Some test cases:

| Registration | ICAO code (hex) | ICAO code (decimal) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N17CA | A11707 | 10557191 |
| N1PP | A00155 | 10486101 |
| N959ZP | AD5863 | 11360355 |
| N999ZZ | ADF669 | 11400809 |

You can assume no invalid inputs will be given.

Comment: `s/numbers/digits/`

Answer (score 1):

## [Validate a codice fiscale](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269468/100234)

Answer (score 1):

## [The TAK function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269557/78410)

Answer (score 1):

This is my first challenge here, and I know I'm not supposed to start with a KotH. But I had this idea and I think it is simple enough while allowing more advanced strategies, so here it is:

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

## Tank Game

There are **two tanks** on a **16×16 toroidal grid** (wrapping in both directions), one starting at `(0, 0)` and its opponent starting at `(8, 8)`. The objective is to occupy the enemy base (starting point) without getting shot.
Some grid cells are walls, which tanks can't move, shoot or see through.
Each submission includes 2 separate programs that form a team, a *commander* and a *tank driver*. Direct communication between them is not allowed, but actions of the commanders are visible to the drivers, **allowing you to encode some information that way**.

### The commander

- Sees the entire map and the positions of the tanks.
- Can build or destroy walls.

### The tank

- Has very limited vision but knows its position.
- Sees the actions of both the friendly and the enemy commander.
- Can move in a straight line up to 3 cells.
- Can shoot in a straight line.

### Details of the game

The tanks and commanders take turns in the following order:

1. Commander of 1st submission
2. Tank driver of 2nd submission
3. Commander of 2nd submission
4. Tank driver of 1st submission

Although from an outside perspective your tank may start at either `(0, 0)` or `(8, 8)`, **the map and all other coordinates provided to your programs (including enemy actions) will be translated by the controller to make it look like your tank started at `(0, 0)` and has to go to `(8, 8)`.** This is done so your program doesn't have to check where it started from.

The starting position looks like this:

```
      | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15 <--- Coordinates observed by Tank 1
      | 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7 <--- Coordinates observed by Tank 2
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 0  8 |T1|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 1  9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 2 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 3 11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 4 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 5 13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 6 14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 7 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 8  0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |T2|  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
 9  1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
10  2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
11  3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
12  4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
13  5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
14  6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
15  7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
^^ ^^
|| ++---- Coordinates observed by Tank 2
++---- Coordinates observed by Tank 1

T1: Starting position of Tank 1, target of Tank 2
T2: Starting position of Tank 2, target of Tank 1
```

The **commander** receives two arguments, `map` and `enemyAction`:

- `map: (x: number, y: number) => Cell`:

  - A `Cell` is one of the following:

    - `' '` (space): empty cell
    - `'#'`: wall
    - `'F'`: friendly tank
    - `'E'`: enemy tank
  - `x` and `y` wrap around (mod 16).
  - You can't directly modify the map
- `enemyAction: Action`

  - ```
    type Action = { action: 'B'|'D', x: number, y: number } | null
    ```
  - The last action of the enemy commander.
  - Given only for convenience, it could be computed from the map.

And must return one of the following actions:

- `{ action: 'B', x: number, y: number }`:

  - Builds a wall.
  - Walls can not be built on the two bases (`(0,0)` and `(8,8)`) and on cells with tanks. Attempting to do so is an error.
- `{ action: 'D', x: number, y: number }`:

  - Destroys a wall.
  - Attempting to destroy a non-existing wall is an error.
- `null`:

  - Does nothing.

The **tank driver** receives four arguments:

- `x: number, y: number`: position of your tank
- `friendlyAction: Action, enemyAction: Action`: the last actions of the friendly and enemy commanders.

And must return one of the following actions:

- `{ action: 'M', direction: Direction, distance: number }`

  - Move the tank (up to 3 cells in a straight line, instantly).
  - `Direction` is one of the following:

    - `'U'`: negative `y` direction (up)
    - `'L'`: negative `x` direction (left)
    - `'D'`: positive `y` direction (down)
    - `'R'`: positive `x` direction (right)
  - `1 <= distance <= 3`
  - If the tank can't move `distance` cells because a wall or the enemy tank is in the way, it stops moving before colliding with that (it will not move at all if the obstacle is directly in front of it).
- `{ action: 'S', direction: Direction }`

  - Shoot.
  - The bullet travels in a straight line until it hits a wall or a tank, instantly.
  - If you hit the enemy tank, you immediately win the round 2-0.
  - You can't shoot yourself.
- `{ action: 'L', callback: (Result) => void }`

  - Look around (in straight lines in all 4 directions).
  - ```
    type Result = { U: number, L: number, D: number, R: number, enemyDirection: Direction | null }
    ```

    - `U`, `L`, `D` and `R` are the lengths of empty cells in the respective directions.
    - `enemyDirection` is the relative direction of the enemy tank, if visible. If there are no walls in the row/column, it will be the direction which the enemy is closer in.

### Scoring

- Reaching `(8,8)` and surviving until your next turn: win 3-0
- Shooting down the enemy tank: win 2-0
- Reaching turn number 40 without a winner: draw 1-1
- Throwing an error or returning invalid action: lose 0-3

### Technical details

The submissions must consist of two separate programs written in [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript). The programs may not use any APIs that aren't part of the language itself (i.e. browser or Node.js APIs) and may not introduce globally observable changes (including but not limited to prototype pollution and mutating built-in objects). The programs may not run code asynchronously.

To keep the game reproducable, `Math.random()` will be replaced with a seeded PRNG, which you can use for randomness, but please don't introduce any other non-determinism.

The commander must be a script with a function `commander` in the top-level scope. Likewise, the tank driver has to have a function named `tankDriver`. You may create helper functions and variables for storing state (state will be reset after each game).

**Each submission will be run against every other submission in pairs**, 2×5 times for each pair (each submission starting 5 times). The maps will be randomly generated. The submission reaching the highest total score wins the challenge.

The controller is not yet done, I want to get feedback about the challenge first.

Besides the ones listed above, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) also apply.

I reserve my right to disqualify entries that violate the above rules or ones that I deem to be cheating. I will always notify the author in advance and allow them to fix the problems.

Comment: If all tanks start at (0, 0), does that mean multiple tanks can be on the same tile? And also, what do the numbers in `C1 T2 C2 T1` mean?

Comment: @AlanBreadel From an outside perspective, one tank starts at (0,0) and the other at (8,8) as mentioned in the introduction. But both tanks see the world as if the tile they started on is (0,0), so they don't have to use conditional logic to decide if they should go to (0,0) or (8,8). I'll try to clarify this. Also, I can easily remove this rule if it's too confusing. `C1 T2 C2 T1` means "commander of first player; tank of second player; controller of second player; driver of first player"

Comment: Ah, so each tank is paired up with one other tank. Is that other tank with another submission or something else?

Comment: Yeah, 2 tanks at a time. One submission consists of one team of a commander and a driver, controlling one tank and editing the map.

Comment: I'm pretty sure king of the hills are supposed to put all submissions against each other, but this is probably also fine. Maybe a swiss format? (e. g. one tank and commander against every other tank and commander team.)

Comment: Also, (0, 0) and (8, 8) imply a 9x9 grid (assuming those are the edges. I'm a bit confused because it specifies 16x16.) It should be (0, 0) and (7, 7) with 0-based indexing, or (1, 1) and (8, 8) with 1-based indexing.

Comment: This is described near the end, "Each submission will be run against every other submission [...]". Also, I have seen KotH's on this format on CGCC

Comment: The map is 16×16, and toroidal (meaning wrapping around). This means (0,0) and (8,8) are the furthest cells (because to get to (15,15) you could just wrap around from 0 to 15 in two steps).

Comment: If a tank moves right say, 5 squares, is that instant or does it take 5 turns with 1 square per turn?

Comment: I'll have to clarify that. Tanks can move up to 3 cells *instantly*. They can move longer than 3 cells in multiple turns

Comment: So for example I try to move 7 tiles, I'll move 3 in one turn, 3 in the next, and 1 in the turn after that, right? But then I decide I want to do something else on the second or third turn. Can I stop the movement and do something else or does it override everything?

Comment: I already edited my post, see the edit. You can't return "move 7 tiles", that is an error. You'd have to go "move 3", "move 3", "move 1" to move 7 in effect.

Answer (score 1):

## Demonstrate that 1³+2³+...+n³ = (1+2+...+n)²

The following image is a proof without words that \$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\right)^2\$, or in other words, the sum of the first n cubes equals the square of the sum of the first n positive integers.

[image]

The image contains (the equivalent of) 1 square with side length 1, 2 squares with side length 2, etc up to 5 squares with side length 5. The 1x1 squares have a total area of 1x1x1 = 1³, the 2x2 squares have a total area of 2x2x2=2³, and the 5x5 squares have a total area of 5x5x5=5³. Overall, the total area of all the squares is 1³ + 2³ + 3³ + 4³ + 5³.

But, the larger square has a side length of 1+2+3+4+5, and an area of (1+2+3+4+5)². And, since all the small squares take up the same space as the large square, they must have the same total area, so 1³+2³+3³+4³+5³ = (1+2+3+4+5)². This can be shown to work for all positive integers.

The above can also be represented as the following integer matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

This matrix can be thought of as a series of "bands", where each band #n contains all points at coordinates (x, y) where max(x, y) = n. Every point in the first band, containing the point at coordinates `[1, 1]`, contains 1; the second, containing `[[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]]`, and the third, containing `[[1,3],[2,3],[3,3],[3,2],[3,1]]`, contain only 2s, the next 3 bands contain only 3s, and so on up to 5.

Your challenge is to, given a positive integer n, output the corresponding integer matrix for n. The above matrix should be output when 5 is input.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: Can I print this matrix infinitely? Or take `i,j` and output the element in those coordinates?

Comment: @CommandMaster I'm gonna say no to that, I don't really see the point of the first and the second oversimplifies things.

Comment: Looks similar to the one that output \$\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\2&2&3&4\\3&3&3&4\\4&4&4&4\end{matrix}\$

Answer (score 1):

## [Remove falsy rows and columns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269954/remove-falsy-rows-and-columns)

Answer (score 1):

## Is it a coordinate-sum list?

In this challenge, we define a *coordinate-sum list* as a ragged list of positive integers where each value is the sum of its 0-indexed-coordinates in the array. For example, the following ragged list is a coordinate-sum list:

```
[[[0, 1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2]],
 [[1],
  [2, 3, 4],
  3]],
 2]]
```

In this array, the 4 is the third item of the second item of the second item of the list, or `arr[1][1][2]` (0-indexing), which gives it the coordinate `[1, 1, 2]`, which sums to 4. Likewise, the 0 is `arr[0][0][0]` and has the coordinate `[0, 0, 0]` which sums to 0, and this is true for all items in the list.

This, however, is *not* a coordinate-sum list:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 6, 5],
 3]
```

Although all the other entries are the sums of their coordinates, the 6 at the third item of the third row has coordinate `[2, 2]`, which sums to 4, but its value is 6, so this is not a coordinate-sum list.

Your challenge is to, given a nonempty ragged list of positive integers containing no empty lists at any level, determine whether it is a coordinate-sum list. You may instead validate the input via 1-indexing (i.e. `[[2, 3], [3, 4, 5], 2]` would be valid).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

All of these use 0-indexing. If your answer uses 1-indexing, add to each value its depth in the list.

**Truthy**

```
[0]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], 2]
[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5]]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 1, [2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7], 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
[[[[0, 1], [1, 2], 2], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]], [[[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]], [[2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]], [2, 3]]
[[[[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]], [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]], [[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]], [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]], [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]]], [[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]], [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]], [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]], [[[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]], [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]], [[5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]], [[[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]], [[5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]], [[6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11]]]]]
```

**Falsy**

```
[2]
[[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
[[[1, 2, 3], 4, [3, 4, 5]], [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]], [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8], [6, [7, 8], 8]]]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[[4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Why does it matter that the array is [othogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_array)?

Comment: @pajonk It doesn't, it was mostly because I didn't want to make things unnecessarily hard for langs like C and haskell which don't (natively) have ragged lists. You're right that almost all approaches would work for ragged lists, and I'm just going to change it to that. (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. We have different definitions of orthogonal and array - for me an array is simply a non-ragged list and [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_array) is a specific property related to arrangement of columns in the array. That said, I personally would prefer non-ragged lists (arrays) in this challenge, as this would be easier for languages supporting matrices (and higher dimension generalisations) like R or Octave.

Answer (score 1):

## [Search the deepest depths of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/271303/100664)

Comment: "multidimensional array" is a bit of a confusing term here, it's really a *ragged* list/array.

Answer (score 1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Print the largest hidden double

Given a sting of space delimited words, find the longest word such that, when that word is replaced with spaces, it is still a subsequence of the remaining string. Then, replace everything, *except* for one such subsequence, with spaces. Print the result

### example:

input:

`that was esoteric and awesome man dope`

longest applicable word: `awesome`

output:

`a  w   eso                  m      e`

### Extra rules / Clarifications

- You may always assume a solution
- Input will only be ascii letters a-z and spaces
- Input will be either all uppercase or all lowercase, whichever is most convenient for the solver
- You must output leading spaces unless that is absolutely impossible for your language in general, but trailing spaces may be removed

#### meta:

i havent written a challenge in so long - how much of this is salvageable and how much can i clear up haha

Comment: Will there always be a valid solution? Eg. `a dog jumps` has no answer

Comment: @ATaco oh yea good question! I think these are better if you can always assume a solution so I'll add that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

## [Magical BF: BF code that works in two ways](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/271735/78410)

---

### Meta

- This is basically a resurrection of [this closed challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/215747/78410) but with different scoring. It was closed based on [the policy about multipart challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/78410). I believe the most problematic part (copying parts of solutions) is solved by competing for each task separately. I also believe that this challenge is better served as one than five separate challenges, since there are some general techniques that transfer well across tasks (trust me, I solved all five tasks before posting this) and posting five of these would look spammy and unoriginal. Please leave comments if you think this version is off-topic.

Comment: Where does tape head start?

Comment: Tape head (data pointer) starts at the leftmost cell.

Comment: Is "Author" you or the source?

Comment: Those are my best scores.

Answer (score 1):

[Lattice points visible from the origin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271695/lattice-points-visible-from-the-origin)

Answer (score 1):

## [Can I Clear The Grid?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/271974) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Suggest case `RGRG` in case someone click on non-empty cell

Comment: Provide link to [english version](https://en.gamesaien.com/game/color_tiles/) instead?

Comment: @Mukundan314 didn't realize there was one; thanks

Comment: @l4m2 good suggestion, added

Answer (score 1):

## Swingin' Four Operations!

Before, I found [this song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swingin%27_the_Alphabet) which has no meaning other than to combine all the consonants and vowels in the English alphabet. This challenge is similar, however, instead of outputting the song, your programs should output a modification which is basically addition, subtraction, multiplication and division tables of small integers up to 12, but presented in a format similar to the song.

Your challenge is to write a program that takes no input and outputs the four operation tables, where the operation inputs (first input from 1 to 10, second input from 1 to 12, both inclusive, 1 omitted for both inputs in the tables for multiplication and division) and output are seperated by spaces, the columns are seperated by commas followed by spaces and the rows are separated by dots followed by new lines. For division, non-integer outputs are rounded off to two decimal places. Each table is separated by two newlines.

The last two columns (11 and 12) don't contain the first parameter of the modification and are only separated by spaces. The required output is in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TCGauBnZ).

Rules:

- You are not allowed to use external resources, such as the internet.
- You cannot use compression algorithms, such as gzip or bzip2, unless you include the full algorithm in your code.
- Use any language, shortest code in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

Comment: Great challenge for writing reusable code and formatting numbers. I've got a few questions: 1) You say that it should output the tables for small integers up to 12. Why are the matrices in the pastebin link 10 by 12? 2) Does 'You are not allowed to use external resources, such as the internet' mean you may not do research (which would be a little weird for answering an online question) or you may not use an API (which is generally not allowed for codegolf)?

Comment: @Cactusroot It does not specify that *all* of the small integer pairs are outputted. Also, 'You are not allowed to use external resources, such as the internet' means you may not use an API.

Comment: Sorry, I added the question. Now I got it, but 'the text in this pastebin' may be a little ambiguous. I believe you can define it precisely as "Any of the four modification tables, where the modification inputs and output are separated by spaces, the columns are separated by commas followed by spaces and the rows are separated by dots followed by new lines, with a trailing separation. The last two columns (11 and 12) don't contain the first parameter of the modification and are only separated by spaces"

Comment: @Cactusroot Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## [Odds for second smallest prime factor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/272276/odds-for-second-smallest-prime-factor)

Answer (score 1):

**Complement of a set of ranges**

Consider a shop that exists for a given range of time.
At certain times during the shop's existence items can go on sale.
These items will be on sale for at least one unit of time.

**Challenge**

Given such a shop, and the times it has items for sale, find the mutually-exclusive ranges of time
when the shop is not selling anything.

Your inputs will be: a two-length array that represents the range of time the shop exists for. An array, where each element is a two-length array that represents a range of time that an item was on sale for.

your output will be: An array, where each element is a two-length array that represents a range of time that no item was on sale for. Where no element's range should overlap another's range.

All values defining a time range will consist of positive integers (or zero).

**Example**

A shop exists for the time range `[0, 10]`.

An item is put up for sale during the time range `[5, 8]`. Another item is put up for sale during the time range `[2, 3]`. Another item is put up for sale during the time range `[4, 6]`.

Thus the shop is selling nothing from time `0` to `2`, `3` to `4`, and `8` to `10`.

```
Inputs: [0, 10] and [[5, 8], [2, 3], [4, 6]]

Output: [[0, 2], [3, 4], [8, 10]]
```

**Extra info**

You may assume that the input time ranges overlap on a common boundary.
i.e. items on sale for `[1, 3]` and `[3, 4]` is effectively a sale for `[1, 4]`.

No time range (input or output) should span less than one unit of time:
i.e. `[1, 1]` or `[7, 7]` is not permitted.

In case this seems ambiguous, the input time ranges can be thought of as closed intervals.
Whilst the output time ranges can be thought of as open intervals. All the values used
are whole numbers, however the ranges they represent are continuous. i.e. the open interval
'[1, 2]' which does not contain any integers, still represents a continuous span of time between
'1' and '2' (non inclusive on both sides).

**Test cases**
(first array is the time for which the shop exists, second is the times for which items were on sale)

```
[0, 100] [[3, 7], [2, 5], [17, 54], [99, 100]] -> [[0, 2], [7, 17], [54, 99]]

[7, 20] [[8, 17], [12, 13], [14, 17], [9, 16], [18, 19]] -> [[7, 8], [17, 18], [19, 20]]

[1, 2] [[1, 2]] -> []
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 1):

###### 8-bit AVR integer division

[Impatience got the better of me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/272250/121071)

Answer (score 0):

## Test for Irreducible Complexity (Check for Redundant Characters)

I may need some additional help coming up with the full spec for this competition.  As of right now, this is just a concept.

Many interesting questions, such as the "42" question in this sandbox, involve finding the longest program which is not reducible.  This means that no set of characters can be removed and still allow the program to function as desired.

The basic idea is that your program will test a Base Program to make sure that it contains no redundant characters.  The input will consist of:

- Base Program (in the same language as your answer)
- Expected Output

Your program will simply evaluate all possible subsequences of the Base Program and verify that none of them give the Expected Output.

This challenge actually has a utility value to several other challenges.  For example, it verifies the results of a "longest non-reducible"-type challenge. In addition, it could make sure that a golfed solution cannot be golfed further.

I assume that the winning criteria will be fastest program, as cycling through all the possibilities takes a long time.

### Problems

A sequence of length N has 2^N subsequences.  Even if each evaluation is done very quickly, it might be unfeasible to test any program with more than 20 or so characters in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Problem: some subsequences of legitimate answers may be pretty dangerous to the environment. You don't want to `eval` just everything.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes that actually is a serious problem.  To what extent is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Forbidding any program with dangerous subsequences? :-)

Comment: A more reasonable (but very difficult) solution would be the requirement to implement a sandbox.

Comment: Even without dangerous behavior, the halting problem will be an issue: it's hard to tell whether a shortened program will terminate at all, especially for every conceivable input.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? The problem of testing if two functions/programs/turing-complete things are equivalent is undecidable - I'm fairly sure it's reasonable easy to constract a brainfuck program that you can't tell if you can remove even a single character.

Comment: Extending on my previous comment -  Let's assume you have a solution to this. Take a brainfuck program you want to test if halts. Let it reduce it, now you have an equivalent irreducible program. Add `+.` in the end of it, and then try to reduce it again. If the code never halts, that `+.` is reducible and when you'll run it again it will be removed. Otherwise it's important, so it will be kept. The halting problem is undecidable, therefor this is undecidable.

Comment: You can also get its undecidablility from that in Unary it will tell you if a given program is minimal, which is known to be undecidable as well

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) [generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Wordlist detector

You are to write a program which, given a list of words, constructs a regular expression to match all these words but nothing else. Both your program and the constructed regular expressions are to be as short as possible.

### Input and Output

Input comes on standard input and consists of one line giving *n*, the total number of words, followed by *n* lines with one word each. The number of words will be less than 1000, the length of each word less than 30. Words will consist only of lower case ASCII letters, i.e. `a-z`. You may choose to ignore the first line and use EOF instead to end the list.

Output shall be written to standard output. It consists of a single line, giving a POSIX extended regular expression to match these words and no others. Since input for this regex is *not* restricted to letters only, elements like `.` or `[^…]` won't make too much sense, which limits the language in a natural way. You may choose whether you want to terminate the line with a newline or not. Programs *may* choose to print multiple lines of output, in which case only the last one will be used for scoring. So you might print intermediate results and continue searching for improvements.

### Test cases

Each submission may be accompanied by *one* regular expression. When scoring the submissions, I'll use this regular expression to reconstruct a word list from it. The code to do this reconstruction can be found at the end of this post. The reconstructed word list must fit the input specification above in terms of word count and length. It would be nice if your own program would be able to regenerate that regular expression from the word list, but that is not a strict requirement. But please don't paste bogus programs just to submit a challenging regular expression, though.

**These test cases will be collected and fed to all programs for scoring.**

### Scoring

The final score of each program will be the program size plus the size of all its generated regular expressions for the inputs collected from submitted answers, including the example from this question. So short code which produces too long results might get beaten by longer code which generates shorter expressions.

*Does this still qualify as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?*

Submissions which generate an incorrect regular expression for one of the test cases will be disqualified, as will those which don't terminate in the allotted time. You can use the input reconstruction program below to check whether a produced regular expression does encode the correct word list.

### Requirements

All submissions are welcome, but in order to include your submission in the tournament, it must be executable with reasonable effort on my Linux machine. It shouldn't depend on any exotic libraries, or any specialized ones which take too much work away from your own program. It must operate in reasonable time, say no more than five minutes per input. Your output must be reproducible, so if you use randomization at some point, please seed the randomizer, and please don't terminate an improove loop by a timer measuring execution time or some such.

### Tournament times

I'll run the first major tournament two weeks after posting this question. I'll include a table of the results in this question. I'll try to run tournaments repeatedly as late submissions arrive, but I'll not promise any regular schedule.

### Example

An very simple example application would be in Python 3 (53 chars):

```py
print('|'.join(input() for i in range(int(input()))))
```

And here is a test case which could be posted along with the program, although this program obviously doesn't generate exactly this concise output:

```
bann?ana|ap(fel|ple)|s[ou]n|[hs](a|ou)nd
```

The expansion of that expression could be turned into the following example input, which need not be posted as part of an answer since it can be deduced from the regular expression:

```
10
banana
bannana
apfel
apple
son
sun
hand
hound
sand
sound
```

### Regex expander program

And here is a program to turn regular expressions into word lists, again written in Python 3.

```py
#!/bin/env python3
concat = set(('',))
altin = set(('',))
altout = set()
prev = None
stack = []
regex = iter(input())
for ch in regex:
    if ch == '(':
        stack.append((concat, altin, altout))
        altin = concat
        altout = set()
        prev = None
    elif ch == ')':
        concat.update(altout)
        prev, altin, altout = stack.pop()
    elif ch == '|':
        altout.update(concat)
        concat = altin
    elif ch == '[':
        ch = regex.__next__()
        cls = []
        while ch != ']':
            if ch == '-':
                crange = range(ord(cls[-1]), ord(regex.__next__()) + 1)
                cls.extend(map(chr, crange))
            else:
                cls.append(ch)
            ch = regex.__next__()
        prev = concat
        concat = set(w + c for w in prev for c in cls)
    elif ch == '?':
        concat.update(prev)
        prev = None
    elif ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z':
        prev = concat
        concat = set(w + ch for w in prev)
    else:
        raise Exception("Illegal input")
if stack:
    raise Exception("Unclosed group")
concat.update(altout)
words = sorted(concat)
print(len(words))
print('\n'.join(words))
```

This is restricted to the part of regular expression syntax which I expect for this answer. If you have good reason to use something I did not consider, feel free to do so although I will likely have to update this code to cope with it. If you find a bug, please let me know.

Comment: This is just [Meta regex golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17718/194) under the constraint that the two lists between them cover all possible words. Given that some people are tackling that existing question on that basis, this would qualify for closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

### Rhymalator

(at the point, it's just something that came to me before i wake up, so it may need some adjusting, and i'd like some feedback as to if this could be fun)

---

The code challenge is to write a program that takes as input a calculation in Reverse Polish Notation and outputs the result. It must at least implement `+ - * /`. It 
So far so easy, but to make it fun and "artistic", the following restriction applies:

- The source code must rhyme when read. Example in PHP

  ```
  $iterator = str_split($a);
  foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value){
      if ($key > 3){
          ++$virtue;
      }
  }
  ```

  (the rhyme is on value-virtue)
- Lines whitout readable characters count as whitespace (the two lines with `}` in the example)

  [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: How does that example rhyme...?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow well, i'm not really a poet, that's why i propose it as a challenge for others :p. if you have a better example i'll replace it

Answer (score 0):

## Implement Kalah [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The game of Kalah is a two-player board game in the Mancala family. Your implementation must:

- Identify the active player ("Player 1" or "Player 2")
- Display board state (in format specified below)
- Accept input to allow that player to move (using index system below)
- Announce a winner ("Player *N* wins")

## Overview

Each player has a line of six spaces, called *houses*, and one additional space called a *store*. Each space holds *seeds*, which move from house to house in a counter-clockwise direction. The objective is to fill your store with seeds.

You must represent the board in the following two-row format with stores offset, where `HH` is a house and `SS` is a store:

```
SS HH HH HH HH HH HH
   HH HH HH HH HH HH SS
```

The top row represents the number of seeds in player #1's spaces, and the bottom row represents the seeds in player #2's spaces. The `S` in each row is the respective player's store (player #1's is top-left, #2's is bottom right). Single-digit values should include a leading space.

In this challenge, user-input will identify each house numerically. Use a left-to-right, indexed-from-one scheme for both sides:

```
S 1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5 6 S
```

Note that the players' stores are not numbered, because seeds placed in the store never move out.

### Rules

Wikipedia has a [good summary of the game and its rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalah):

> 1. At the beginning of the game, three seeds are placed in each house.
> 2. Each player controls the six houses and their seeds on his/her side of the board. His/her score is the number of seeds in the store to his/her right. [Clarification: from our perspective, player 1's store is to the left, player 2's store is to the right.]
> 3. Players take turns sowing their seeds. On a turn, the player removes all seeds from one of the houses under his/her control. Moving counter-clockwise, the player drops one seed in each house in turn, including the player's own store but not his/her opponent's.
> 4. If the last sown seed lands in the player's store, the player gets an additional move. There is no limit on the number of moves a player can make in his/her turn.
> 5. If the last sown seed lands in an empty house owned by the player, and the opposite house contains seeds, both the last seed and the opposite seeds are captured and placed into the player's store. [Clarification: moves that end on an *opponent's* empty house end normally without a capture.]
> 6. When one player no longer has any seeds in any of his/her houses, the game ends. The other player moves all remaining seeds to his/her store, and the player with the most seeds in his/her store wins.

## Example

(Parenthetical text should not appear in actual output.)

```
Player 1
 0  3  3  3  3  3  3
    3  3  3  3  3  3  0
> 2                      (prompt arrow and line break
                          are purely optional)
 Player 2
 1  1  0  3  3  3  3
    4  3  3  3  3  3  0
> 4

Player 2  (P2 gets a bonus turn from rule #4)
 1  0  3  3  3  3  3
    4  3  3  0  4  4  1
> 5

Player 1  
 1  0  3  3  3  4  4
    4  3  3  0  0  5  2
> 4

Player 1  (P1 captures P2's seeds in space 1)
 6  0  4  4  0  4  4
    0  3  3  0  0  5  2
...

Player 2
12  0  0 10  0  1  0
    0  0  0  0  0  1 13
 > 6

Player 1 wins            (because the non-finishing players gets
                          all remaining seeds on their side, it's 23-14)
```

---

**Meta question:** Would this be improved by removing some of the rules?

Comment: Do the players run the game once and then take it in turns to take moves, with the process ending only when the game ends? Or do they run the program once per move?

Answer (score 0):

[This is the first time I'm using the sandbox.  I want to get feedback/suggestions before posting the question.]

Make a spider web (standard, orb type) that fills frame in the ratio of n:m, where n, m are input integers.  You may use the example below as a model (but you don't need to use labels).

[image: spider web]

Your web should have *multiple radii*, at least 4 of which attach directly to the frame. The remaining radii should attach to the *outer outline* (perimeter) of the web. The web should have at least 15 radii. The mesh spacing should be more or less uniform spacing (although occasional weaving mistakes" or crossings are encouraged and will receive a bonus).

This is code-golf, so the shortest code (minus bonuses) wins.

---

**Bonuses** (to be removed from the number of characters in your code).  Bonuses are awarded for the following features that reflect the architecture of an actual web (as opposed to a perfectly symmetric rendering).  They are somewhat greater than usual as an incentive for attention to detail and realism.

-mesh spiral instead of concentric circles: 40 pts

-assymmetric web: 31 pts. (e.g. height of capture area greater than width)

-irregularly spaced radii: 42 pts

-distinct segments between radii (straight or crooked, but not the arc of a circle): 32 pts

-outer and inner outline clearly distinct from the spiral: 41 pts

-irregular outer outline: 20 pts

-2 or more easily observable reverses in spiral: 40

The accept will be awarded on Feb. 20, 2014.

Comment: If there are bonuses then it isn't [tag:code-golf], by definition. It's not clear what output formats are acceptable. I'm not sure what you mean by "distinct segments between radii". "2 or more easily observable reverses" seems problematic: the ease of observing reverses is subjective, and might in addition depend on input and/or on the random numbers obtained. The weighting for the bonuses seems very arbitrary: is there any justification for it?

Comment: Re: bonuses, I should probably decide on the features I want included in the web, thereby eliminating bonuses altogether. Distinct segments means that there should be 2 straight mesh segments between radius n and radius n+2 (not sure whether this should be required in instructions to be updated.) Will give reverses more thought.

Answer (score 0):

### Write a PHP Code Golfer [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Since my currently daily programming is in PHP, I tend to try the challenges on the site using that language, but frequently I large program because of the verbosity of the language. And then I have to strip it for presentation...

But this is not a tips question, it's an eviscerating challenge.

The objective is to write a program in the language of your choice that takes a PHP file and outputs a golfed valid PHP file with the same functionality.

The scoring will be the average reduction in percent of the result of running the program with 3 selected files (not yet selected, I was thinking of some open source library)

The output file should run on at least 5.4 (so shorthand arrays, function dereference, traits are available)

Since the score is the difference between the ungolfed and golfed files, techniques beyond minifying are encouraged, such as using code subtitution, eval, compression, $$ (variable variables), dereferencing...

---

Scoring example: The 3 sources have 450, 1200 and 3500 chars respectively

Answer 1 
results lenghts: 250, 1000, 3300 
reduction: 200, 200, 200 (44%, 17%, 6%) average: 22%

Answer 2 
results lenghts: 350, 1050, 3150 
reduction: 100, 150, 350 (22%, 13%, 10%) average: 15%

In this case Answer 1 would win, even tough both answers got the same total reduction (-600 chars)

Comment: It's a specialisation of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3652/194 , so would likely be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I saw it. is similar, but I include an objetive goal and score.
have any idea on how to make it more unique?

Comment: "Making it shorter" is too broad, can I just delete some comments? If not, can I only shorten one variable and it's ok. It's not very interesting like this...

Comment: @Fabinout the objective is golfing the code. If you only remove some characters, I doubt you'll get a good score

Comment: Alright, the criterion is the size of the output source code. good clarification.

Comment: Sum the bytes with the percents or separately? Also, no matter what sources you choose, make sure to paste the code into your questions; who knows when the code in the library will change?

Comment: i'll edit the bit about scoring (with examples) tomorrow (when i come back to work). I'll post the test sources as a pastebin, but I'll wait to choose them until the question is polished enough and someone consider it interesting enough

Comment: Is there anyone more with questions? is still possible that it will be marked as a duplicate? or can i choose the sources and publish it?

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Karnaugh-map calculator

Given an input of a truth table, generate a corresponding [K-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

**Input**:

Input will be of the form `10110001` where each bit is a row of a truth table. Count from the left to the right; so that input would be a table of:

```
i2i1i0 f
0 0 0|1
0 0 1|0
0 1 0|1
0 1 1|1
1 0 0|0
1 0 1|0
1 1 0|0
1 1 1|1
```

*Max 4 variables will be inputted*

**K-maps** (a small explanation):

K-maps are a way of simplifying boolean-algebra expressions.

Let's say we have 4 variables: a, b, c, d. Let the truth-table be `1110101001111111` (and the columns on the truth table be labeled, from left to right: a, b, c, d). Arrange the variables like so:

```
   cd
ab\   00 01 11 10
   00
   01
   11
   10
```

Note the [grey-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_code) counting scheme.

Fill in the table with the corresponding values from the truth table:

```
   cd
ab\   00 01 11 10
   00 1  1  0  1
   01 1  0  0  1
   11 0  1  1  1
   10 1  1  1  1
```

Group the values in rectangles whose dimensions are the largest possible powers of two. Note that this table signifies a torus, so wrap over the left and right edges.

[image]

The expression for the truth table is the `or`s of the `and` of the unchanging elements. For this, that would be:

Purple group: ¬b ∧ ¬c (for 0's, make them 1 by notting the value)
Green group: ¬a ∧ ¬d
Black group: a ∧ d
Blue group: b ∧ ¬d

Expression: (¬b ∧ ¬c) ∨ (¬a ∧ ¬d) ∨ (a ∧ d) ∨ (b ∧ ¬d)

**Output**:

- Generate a 2D K-map (for more variables, add on either side) and show the grouping. K-map must be of the form I used. For less variables, remove rows or columns and change the list on the top left corner.
- assume alphabetical ordering on the variables, that is, the first variable is `a`, second: `b`, third: `c`, and so on.
- Also show the expression. Rather than use the unicode characters, the following is permissible:

  ```
  ~ instead of ¬
  * instead of ∧
  + instead of ∨
  ```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

---

Edit: Possible duplicate: [More fun with gates: Karnaugh simplification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12300/more-fun-with-gates-karnaugh-simplification)

Comment: I think the grouping is not unique and therefore I might choose the most basic grouping (i.e. none).

Comment: Although @Howard's concern is partially answered by "rectangles whose dimensions are the largest possible powers of two", it's not obvious to me why you haven't also circled the entire row `10` and the bottom-right quadrant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right - didn't read that line. But still my main concern is correct: it is not unique. Or as your remark shows it is not optimal if you choose all rectangles.

Comment: Also for higher number of variables you have to either go to `n` dimensional K-maps or you won't find all possible *rectangles* (they are no longer adjacent in the matrix).

Comment: @PeterTaylor In priority: Biggest rectangles, then least number. That is a big rectangle, but it is redundant with the others because every `1` in it is already circled.

Comment: @Howard Good point. I'll restrict it to 4 or less variables.

Comment: For the expression: rather than using `A` and `V`, why not `*` and `+`? That's fairly conventional use of field notation to represent GF(2).

Comment: Ahem. `OR` is, of course, not the same as `+` in GF(2). But `*` and `+` is still the conventional notation for operations over the Boolean semiring.

Answer (score 0):

## Create diagonal code

Your task is to create a program that outputs `d=s*sqrt(2)`.

**Specs:**

- Your program must be at least 4 lines long;
- `d=s*sqrt(2)` cannot be hardcoded **as is** (so using ascii, compression, encoding, etc. is allowed and encouraged);
- For each line of code `n`, pick up the `n`th character. The string obtained this way must be a valid program in a programming language of your choice, that must be different from the one you used for the main program. The obtained program **must** compile successfully, but it can throw errors, exceptions, etc.;
- If at the `n`th line there is no `n`th character, you can consider that character as a **whitespace** or a **newline**. This cannot be done for the first 4 lines, which must be long at least `n` non-whitespace characters.
- Your main program **must** end successfully (no errors, exceptions, etc.);
- Internet access is forbidden;
- Most upvoted answer in 2 weeks wins.

Happy coding!

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

---

I was unsure about making this a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) with several bonuses (polyglot answer, secondary program still valid, etc...).

---

#### Some bonuses for the code-challenge version:

Your valid answer starts with **0** points. You gain:

**+10** if the secondary answer hides a third answer in it;
**+15** for any other hidden answer;
**+5** for every hidden answer that runs and ends successfully, without any problem;
**+10** if your main answer is a polyglot;
**+15** for every hidden answer that is a polyglot;

---

Which version would you prefer? Is there something you would change/improve in this question?

I personally like the [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) one, but the **KISS** principle (Keep it simple, stupid!) reminds me that I may be wrong.

Comment: It's trivial to make the diagonal program be just whitespace (many scripting languages will accept this as a program) or `H   ` (valid program in H9Q+).

Comment: Nowhere does it say that the *diagonal* program must output your magic string: it doesn't even have to execute correctly. Your amendment doesn't really fix things: I can now have the second line be `#H`, the third be `#HH`, etc.

Comment: You're right; Don't know why, on a second read I messed up the meaning of your comment. Anyway, I suppose this excludes [tag:code-challenge] unless I/we don't find a way to avoid such trivial solutions. I guess [tag:popularity-contest] would still be ok, since more interesting solutions could be found, right?

Comment: I think my views on [tag:popularity-contest] in general are well known. On further reflection, there are enough languages in which any string of bytes is a valid program that I don't think this question can work as is. If you want to save it, I think you need to look at doing something like a very difficult double-quine.

Comment: Thinking about quines and diagonals (which was the "spirit" of the question), what about a sort of mini-quine? The main program would have to display `d=s*sqrt(2)` only, and its diagonal must reproduce the code used to display the magic string (no comments allowed). It could be tagged [tag:code-golf] or [tag:code-challenge].

Answer (score 0):

Title: Implement ROT-13... in ROT-13

Content:

Challenge: Implement [ROT-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot_13) in code that works as both itself and as the ROT-13 version of itself.

#### Scoring:

Your score is calculated as a percentage of **used, ROT-13 eligible bytes in total of both versions of the program** divided by **total bytes (all characters) of both versions**.

A **used, ROT-13 eligible byte** is any character that is not part of a comment or ignored by the compiler/interpreter. For example, any character in a brainfuck program that is not `+-<>[],.`  is not considered a used byte, and any character in a C program including and after `//` or inside `/* */` is not considered a used byte. All special symbols in APL are not considered used, as are all characters in a Whitespace program (sorry).

Example scoring:

#### C: 21/32 = 65.625%

```
main(){printf("Hello World!");}
```

Comment: Originally this question was ROT-47, not ROT-13. The rules are chosen so that choice of language doesn't easily determine the winner; otherwise, whitespace would easily win. When I changed it to ROT-13 I made only [A-Za-z] count so that a language like golfscript or brainfuck would not automatically score 100%. Looking for thoughts on how to capture the idea without making it too "choice of language" dependent.

Comment: Just saying, I have a C answer for the 47-version: http://qp.mniip.com/p/tz pick either of the lines

Comment: @mniip Okay I undeleted it :)

Answer (score 0):

## **Convert input to ASCII Semaphore**

With monitor resolutions getting higher and font sizes getting lower, a good programmer has to make efforts to ensure that output is accessible to the visually impaired.  This can be problematic when the only display is in text. Toward this end, your assignment (if you choose to accept it) is to write a program that converts text input into ASCII art [flag semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore).

### **Input**

1. Your program must accept any letter in the ASCII character set from A to Z (case insensitive) and spaces.
2. The program can accept input in any way that is convenient for the language it is written in (stdin,
   command line, file, etc.).

### **Output**

1. The program should output an ASCII art representation of the input string in flag semaphore. Follow [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore) to see the expected encoding.
2. Line feeds and carriage returns should be interpreted as spaces.
3. Numbers and other non-letters in the input may be ignored.
4. You may use whatever ASCII art representation of the semaphore sender you like, but it must contain a person holding two flags and have distinct arms, legs, head, and flags. It must be at least 10x10 characters.
5. Output may be either horizontal or vertical.

### **Example**

**Input:** `Hello`

**Output:**

```
           ###
           ###
            #
 _____########
|  |       ###
|__|      ####
         # ###
        #  ###
       /   # #
      /\   # #
     /  \  # #
     \  /  # #
      \/  ## ##
                    /\
                   /  \
                  /\  /
                 #  \/
           ###  #
           ### #
            # #
          ####
         # ###
         # ###
         # ###
         # ###
         | # #
         |__ #
         |  |#
         |__|#
          ## ##
                    /\
                   /  \
                  /\  /
                 #  \/
           ###  #
           ### #
            # #
           ###
          ####
         # ###
        #  ###
       #   ###
      /    # #
     /\    # #
    /  \   # #
    \  /   # #
     \/   ## ##
                    /\
                   /  \
                  /\  /
                 #  \/
           ###  #
           ### #
            # #
           ###
          ####
         # ###
        #  ###
       #   ###
      /    # #
     /\    # #
    /  \   # #
    \  /   # #
     \/   ## ##
   /\
  /  \
  \  /\
   \/  #
        #  ###
         # ###
          # #
 _____########
|  |       ###
|__|       ###
           ###
           ###
           # #
           # #
           # #
           # #
          ## ##
```

### **Scoring**

This is code golf.  Shortest code wins.

Comment: define "easily recognisable". Would a simple 3x3 compass (say, with a head if not covered) do? say:`.o.` `-|.` `/|.` ; or even: `...` `xx.` `x..` (read by lines, dots represent spaces)

Comment: @JanDvorak Good catch. Edited to include distinct items that must be present and a minimum size. I'm not exactly sure how to make that rule more clear.

Comment: Define "person holding two flags". Is what I drew a person? Is this a (lying, due to formatting issues) person: `o--`? Are three x's on a vertical line a person?

Comment: @JanDvorak Ack! had to many tabs open and forgot to save my edit. I think number 4 for output *should* cover that.

Comment: Define "distinct arms, legs, head, and flags." But I suggest allowing very small figures as well, otherwise this will turn into  a kolmogorov-complexity-like question with very little of the code actually involving generating a pair of directions.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3628/737). The ascii art is more complex here so perhaps it's not close enough to be called a duplicate...

Comment: I disagree with @JanDvorak: I think this would be better with a fixed output spec which must be followed exactly. That way people can golf their code rather than the output.

Comment: Standard figures seem best to me as well. If you demonstrate a full "clock" of hand positions for the standard figure, then you can require those as output. That's easier to assess than free reign for variations.

Answer (score 0):

With its strange choice of 9 different characters (plus space and newline), the ASCII art version of the FreeBSD logo has always looked to me as if it might be nicely formatted, obfuscated code is some programming language. (Is it?)

````
 ```                        `
s` `.....---.......--.```   -/
+o   .--`         /y:`      +.
 yo`:.            :o      `+-
  y/               -/`   -o/
 .-                  ::/sy+:.
 /                     `--  /
`:                          :`
`:                          :`
 /                          /
 .-                        -.
  --                      -.
   `:`                  `:`
     .--             `--.
        .---.....----.
````

Therefore I would like to challenge you to make it one: Either specify minimal changes to an existing programming language or minimal changes to this piece of ASCII art (making the artwork look different or significantly changing the character set used are definitely major changes), so that the logo, as source code generates meaningful output.

This should be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) challenge, although I wouldn't mind some way of introducing hard scoring and run this as [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

Answer (score 0):

### King of the Hill Fighting

In this game, a player controls 5 bots that attack the other players 5 bots.
Each bot has life points, and has to reduce the other playres lifepoints to zero.
This post is program that tests the controllers. It is in literate haskell.

```
> import Data.Set as S
> import Data.Map as M
```

Here is the arena:

```
    D---G
   /|   |\
  B |   | J
 /|\|   |/|\
A | E---H | L
 \|/|   |\|/
  C |   | K
   \|   |/
    F---I
20  12    4
  16    8   0
```

Positions are denoted by letters

```
> data Positions = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

Each player is presented a map in which their side is the one with A.
Here is code that will reflect it so each player sees their own view.

```
> pairFlip = (\(x, y)->[(x,y), (y,x)])
> reflect = M.fromList $ [(A,L), (B,J), (D,G), (C, K), (E, H), (F, I)] >>= pairFlip
```

Lines denote connections.

```
> connections=S.fromList $
>   [(A,B), (A,C), (B,D), (C, F), (E, D), (E, F), (D, G), (E, H), (F, I)]
>   >>= pairFlip
>   >>= (\(x,y)->[(x,y), (reflect ! x, reflect ! y)])
> 
> connected x y=(x, y) `S.member` connections
```

The numbers below are the number of life points of generation that each bot.

```
> regen = M.fromList $
>   [ (A, 20), (B, 16), (C, 16), (D, 12), (E, 12), (F, 12)
>   , (G, 8), (H, 8), (I, 8), (J, 4), (K, 4), (L, 0)]
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a specification hidden in here somewhere?

Comment: @Peter Taylor Just not done yet.

Comment: You won't get lots of answers if it's limited to Haskell.

Comment: No no no, the above post is also a program for testing it. I will add in code that can take arbitrary programs and use them.

Answer (score 0):

## music theory challenge

Create a program that takes some input in the form of frequency, waveform, and duration that generates an audio stream based on the input.

You can take input parameters however you choose, but if I input (translated to your method) 440Hz, sin(x), 3 seconds,  your program should play or create a file for a sound 3 seconds long at 440 hertz on a sine wave.

Also, any output should be musically correct as far as frequency is concerned.  See
[http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/notefreqs.html) for example frequencies

Since this is a popularity contest, the rest is up to you.  I bid you Good programming!

Oh, and any use of external functions or APIs is ok, as long as they weren't developed specifically for this contest.

Comment: If the program takes "*input in the form of frequency, waveform and duration*" then where do linear functions fit? What do you mean "*output should be musically correct as far as frequency is concerned*" given that the input is frequency? Is it supposed to correct the input: "You said 494Hz but you must mean 493.88Hz"? And simple synth has been done before in various guises: see [tag:music]. To differentiate this and make it non-trivial you could perhaps specify a set of basic synth operations which need to be configurable (e.g. input specifies generators, envelopes, filters, mixers).

Comment: On second thoughts, that would probably work better as a Code Review [Code Challenge](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I didn't even know about Code Review Code Challenges <intrigued>.  Linear isn't the right word...and I think that statement is redundant anyway, so I'll nix it.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to re-write this challenge...I don't know yet whether it'll be here of on CR

Answer (score 0):

## Create the perfect CSS reset stylesheet

Your job is to create a CSS reset stylesheet, That is, a stylesheet that you can apply to any HTML file, and the result will look the same in all webbrowsers. Because we all know that cross-browser interoperability is very important these days, and you want to make your website look pixel perfect everywhere.

The rules:

1. You must be able to throw any valid HTML5 document at it and the result will look the same in the main browsers.
   For simplicity, you can assume that the HTML document does not contain any styles of its own or Javascript that changes anything. Just pure, static HTML that is valid HTML5.
2. The main browsers are Firefox >= 22, Chrome >= 28 and IE >= 10.
3. To avoid solutions like `*{display:none}` (which do indeed make all documents look the same in all browsers, yes) the result must be identical to the document without the stylesheet in one of the browsers.
   In other words, take your browser of choice and make the document look like that in the other browsers.

The winner is the stylesheet that works the best, again, on any HTML file that is valid HTML5 and uses no other styles. I'm not looking at efficiency. If you come up with a 100K stylesheet or one that slows the site down considerably, that doesn't matter, as long as the end result looks good.

---

That's the question so far. Now I have a bit of a problem with "any HTML5 document"; I know I could provide a test document that people can work with, but then you'll get answers that cater to only that particular test case, and that's not what I want. Not sure how to handle this. Ideas?
Also, I want to include Safari as a main browsers, but as I don't have a Mac, I can't test the results on it. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor That breaks rule #3.

Comment: `The result must be identical to the document without the stylesheet in one of the browsers.` I assume you have loaded a webpage without a stylesheet before?  If you mean that it can have the main stylesheets, and we just need to create a modification stylesheet, you should specify that.

Comment: @hosch250 What I mean is that I want the document to retain its basic HTML-ness, so it shouldn't look like plain text. Take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vaTxA/) for example; open it in all browsers, and then add CSS to it so that it looks like (your favourite browser) in all other browsers. If the name of such is "modification stylesheet" rather than "reset stylesheet",  I apologise.

Comment: OK, I was thinking about how most HTML pages rely on CSS stylesheets to even be legible.  If you took the CSS sheet off any webpage, it would not look the same; in fact, if the HTML wasn't laid out good using accessibility techniques, it wouldn't be legible.

Comment: Pixel perfect isn't going to happen because of issues around anti-aliasing: CSS doesn't let you do things like enable ClearType on Safari/OS X or disable it on IE/Win. So the best anyone can do is somehow obtain the default stylesheets for the listed browsers (e.g. [iecss.com](http://www.iecss.com/) but updated) and then find a minimal diff.

Comment: Guys, I'm not interested in solutions to the question right now. I want to know if the question is OK! Specifically if I can get away with not posting a testcase like the fiddle above.

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate pi using a unique method

Your task is to calculate or approximate pi using the most interesting method you know. Well-known things such as using inverse trig functions (asin, acos, atan) or commonly used convergent series are considered uninteresting.

You may calculate pi to any precision desired, but the more precision you can achieve, the better.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this, but I'd like to know if this overlaps too strongly with an existing question.

Comment: If you rule out convergent series, what's left?

Comment: @PeterTaylor If someone knows of a convergent series that isn't on Wikipedia, that would make a good answer. I know of an answer that does not use trigonometry or an approximation, but calculates the digits directly.

Comment: Is it in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html ?  I've got some ancient code which uses a spigot hypergeometric evaluator to compute pi as `3*F(1/2, 1, 1, 8/5 ; 3/5, 4/3, 5/3 | 2/27)`, but I would expect that to count as well-known.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm familiar with it in layman's terms only, but I don't see it there. It could be related to some of them, but I don't see more than a small resemblance. It isn't original with me, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

## I like trees

...so this is a challenge to make me a tree.

Produce a program called tree which takes a single integer argument, N and draws a randomly-generated tree N levels deep, where level 0 is just the trunk.

- Your program must produce visibly different results for at least N=0..5
- The tree ought to not be symmetrical in any axis.
- The tree should be an image
- Tree(5) should mostly fill dimensions of at least 200w*250h
- I should be able to run your tree from a bash prompt, eg. '$ python tree.py 3'

I also accept ferns.

Optionally your tree may be 3d, iterate forever, be colourful, have leaves at level 5, or be lit according to the time of day. However, this is code-golf, so the smallest file wins.

Tags: code-golf

Answer (score 0):

**Foreword**: This might have been done before, but I couldn't find any such cases. I think the scoring is quite fair now, and the challenge quite clear, but any criticism is welcome. Only thing I am not sure of (besides maybe a similar question existing) is whether it is rewarding enough to add a single language or whether a 2 byte solution which just runs in two languages is going to win (is that possible?).

## The challenge

Write a single piece of code that will only output different deterministic integers depending on the language it has been interpreted as.

## Scoring

Length of the code divided by the multiplication of the score of every used language. [Esoteric languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) have score 2 and production languages have score 3. For example, if you have a code of length 120 which runs in whitespace and javascript this will give a score of `120/(2*3)=20`.

## Rules

- Versions and forks: Different versions and forks may count as different languages, provided that the output is not determined by the version or similar constants in any way. In other words: `<?=intval(phpversion())?>` or `1<!--[if IE 8]>1<![endif]-->` is not allowed.
- The outputted integer should be the constant and *only* dependent on the language it is run in.
- Only the most common compiler for a language should be used.
- The code should output nothing besides the integer.
- No two interpretations (languages) of the code may yield the same integer.
- In cases where there is any serious discussions of a language being esoteric, it will be counted as esoteric if no commercial company with at least 50 employees can be pointed to developing it's main product in the discussed language.

  > ^ Blame the sandbox for that last crazy over specific rule

Comment: Define "esoteric." Also, the last time is fairly opinion-based. And what about different versions of the same language? Or similar languages (i.e. C and C++)?

Comment: Yes, a two-byte solution which runs in two languages is arguably possible. The arguments will come around things like what precisely you mean by "*output ... [an] integer*". Is additional non-numeric output (punctuation, `ans - `, or the like) permitted? If so, can the integer be part of an error message from the interpreter? Also expect arguments about whether languages are esoteric or production: it's clear-cut for C and Piet, but there are plenty of languages in much greyer territory.

Comment: @Doorknob: Added a link and a rule regarding esoteric. Addressed the issue regarding forks and versions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Great point regarding additional output! Would you have an example of a language you would consider to be gray? I added an additional note regarding the esoterism, but would like to have a 'gray' language to see whether the added rule would make a clear cut or still keep it gray.

Comment: "Major/generally known" is *highly* opinion-based...

Comment: @Doorknob: Although programmers do tend to think that anything a computer can not parse is opinion based, it is not hard to draw a line there knowing any of the social sciences, but fair enough, let me change that to a something even a programmer is able to comprehend.

Comment: Okay, seriously, now you're just being ridiculous. The reason an objective specification is needed is because two people might disagree with the interpretation of the rule.

Comment: The grey area I was thinking about is mainly functional languages. Common LISP, Haskell, OCAML, and F# all see some serious use; I'm not sure whether any of them meet your updated criterion. I can also report that a two-byte solution which runs in two languages *is* possible, but *wouldn't* win: I've found a three-byte solution which runs in three languages.

Comment: J and K were designed as production languages, but I haven't seen anyone use them as such. What do they count in this chalenge?

Comment: "it will be counted as esoteric if no commercial company with at least 50 employees can be pointed to developing it's main product in the discussed language." - first off, I don't think this kind of data is readily available. Second, I doubt you'll find a company that still codes in Algol, Perl or Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement multi-line lambdas in Python.

[Guido van Rossum said it couldn't be done](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=147358), prove him wrong. Your solution should allow multi-line anonymous functions, like:

```
>>> f = multilinelamba("hour", """
...     if hour > 20 or hour < 6:
...         print "Good night"
...     else:
...         print "Hello world"
...     """)
>>> f(10)
... 'Hello world'
```

Your solution should be as close as possible to the behavior of real `def` or `lambda`. The actual syntax doesn't matter. E.g. you may choose to pass the code as a string as above, or you may find a way to avoid it. The implementation is also open, you may for example define a function, write a preprocessor, or edit the python source, but keep in mind that the solution should fit in the answer, so the last option probably won't work.

Your solution must allow arbitrary python code inside, except the following which is optional:

- recursive use of the `multilinelambda` "statement" inside of the `multilinelambda`
- calling the function recursively, i.e. using `f` inside the `multilinelambda` in the above function
- defining classes and
- importing modules (these two might be too hard)

You must also be able to use a `multilinelambda` as a parameter when calling a function.

You get bonus points:

- If your solution captures outside variables in a closure, like real `def` does
- For correct handling of exceptions in the `multilinelambda`. They should display similarly to when using `def`, and include line number relative to the file.
- For allowing default parameters
- For allowing *args and **kwargs
- If the solution admits any kind of consistent indentation. Two options must be considered:

  - All lines have a common indentation (like in the example above) that can be stipped away.
  - The first line of the body is given on the same line as the `multilinelambda` statement. In this case, all the remaining lines must be checked for consistency. It makes a difference whether the first line starts a block or not. Example:

    ```
    multilinelambda("x", """print "Hello"
                            print "World" """)

    multilinelambda("x, y", """if x > y:
                                   print "case 1" 
                               else:
                                   print "case 2"
                            """)
    ```

  In both cases, I may add or remove the same number of spaces to/from each of the lines following `multilinelambda`.

---

Any ideas for additional criteria? I *personally* don't really care much about picking a winner, this is more about tinkering and proving that it can be done. But in any way, more "unit tests" will only benefit the question.

Btw., I [asked about this kind of question here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/programming-puzzle-asking-for-real-clever-solutions-ok) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

## Split string of powers of 2

I had this idea while playing 2048; Every single power of 2 is unique, even if it contains another power of 2 as a substring because there are none that consist entirely of powers of 2.

For example, the string `"2048409632864"` can be split into `2048, 4096, 32, 8, 64` easily enough, but it can also be split into `2, 0, 4, 8, 4, 0963, 2, 8, 6, 4` with a simple left-to-right algorithm, which is incorrect.

So, the challenge is to correctly split these numbers in the shortest byte count possible. Is this a good idea?

Comment: But 128 can be split into 1 (2**0), 2 (2**1) and 8 (2**3) ...

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24589/194) - and read the comments, because I think a lot of that discussion is relevant to this question.

Comment: Does the program need to split the string into the smallest range possible?  So if you get 2048, do you need go back and convert it into 2, 0, 4, 8?

Comment: also, that no word in a language can be decomposed does not imply that concatenations of words in that language are always unique.

Answer (score 0):

## A "counting" quine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and maybe [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine). Hopefully codegolf.SE isn't tired of quines and quine-derivatives.

The aim of this golf is simple. Write a family of programs *A* and a single program *B* in your language, such that:

- Program *A(N)* produces the source code of *A(N+1)* when run, independent of file name, current date, contents of STDIN, or similar external variables.
- Program *B*, when given the source of *A(N)* as input, returns *N*. Input can be via STDIN, function argument, preinitialized single-character string variable, or language's equivalent.

Your score is the sum of the lengths of *A(0)* and *B* in bytes. Lowest score wins.

I called it a counting quine, because it is easiest to implement like a quine, except it also counts. The purpose of program *B* is to potentially allow for non-numeric changes between the programs in A, such as an increasing line of asterisks or something.

#### Things to consider

Is this too similar to "[Program that creates larger versions of itself (quine-variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21831/5138)?"

Golfscript has a particularly powerful answer to the above question, that could be adapted to this challenge. It seems like it would beat even my best J, which itself is a curt 29 + 10 = 39 bytes. If this question is dissimilar enough to post, are we just going to bite the pillow and let these two duke it out? Is there some kind of restriction that might make this a little harder or more unique?

Alternatively, should this be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)? Maybe it would be more fun or interesting not to constrain cleverness by size requirements.

Comment: Seems potentially even more suited for functional tarpits. I suspect zot might be a contender. But it's certainly the case that the better answers to the other question are trivially adapted, so it would seem to be a duplicate as written. One way of adapting it which might solve that problem is to require *B = A(0)*, or even to generalise that a bit so that *A(N)* with no input / empty input outputs *A(N+1)* and with input of *A(M)* outputs *M+N* in decimal.

Comment: You should give more importance to `max(N)` rather than code size.

Comment: @user80551 What for? That's not really an issue, even for the Golfscript solution, if you assume that time and space are not issues: theoretically N can reach to infinity. The same can be said of my J solution. However, it raises an interesting question: maybe this could be a [code-challenge], affected by the rate at which the program grows? Or maybe we take the max N, if all the programs in A have to be less than a certain filesize? Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

I've put potential issues in **bold**.

We need some XHTML pages to test this on. I suggest http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/schemas/xhtml1-sample.xml#headings.heading

## XHTML Compression Challenge (revision 5)

Design an algorithm to compress XHTML code as efficiently as possible. You must provide programs that do compression and decompression, and a detailed explanation. Input before compression and decompressed output should be identical and both valid XHTML.

The exact specification of XHTML we will be using is XHTML 1.0 Transitional as defined by W3C. This is to make the code easier to deal with - parameter values are always in quotes, there is a distinction between single and container tags, and all tags are properly nested.

This would be a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), so the winner is whoever gets the best compression ratio on <*some test code*>. Obviously the algorithm should work on any HTML!

The sort of thing that I mean is

- not including the `html` tag in the compressed format (as you always know where it is)
- compressing `h1`, `h2` and so on to `1`, `2`, etc.
- compress `title` to `t`

---

The test code (could be an actual webpage) **(where do we get the test code)** would contain a variety of HTML tags, **in "natural abundances"** (you won't suddenly have millions of `kbd` tags, say, but you would have lots of `p` or `br`).

---

The decompressed code and the original MUST be identical!

Or should we allow minute differences like interchanging `<acronym>` with `<abbr>`, or `<strike>` with `<s>`?

Comment: Transforming `<s>test</s>` to `<del>test</del>` is not compression, so I think that the title is misleading. Your example is not good because we can see it as only replacing tags by other tags.

Comment: @n.1 That's not what I mean, I mean that if we compress strikethrough as `s`, then `<s>`, `<strike>` and `<del>` can all compress to `s`. So the compression algorithm can make no distinction between the three, and then it can decompress `s` as any one of the three.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see what are you waiting for. Please add an example of compressed text to see how to calculate the score. And what tags can be *translated*, what about `<i>` to `<em>`, etc.? The rules have to be strict so the users will know what tags can be *translated* to other tags. And this question lacks a input that will be processed by the users to compare the *compression* ratio.

Comment: @n.1 maybe we can scrap the tag translation thing entirely?
It does lack a standard test text to find compression ratio, I was hoping someone would find one.

Comment: @n.1 So, we scrap turning tags into other tags. But we should allow translating between `<br />` and `<br>`, because they are EXACTLY the same. Or should we? (It would be annoying if we didn't.)

Comment: Do you want to judge purely on the compression ratio, regardless of the size of the submitted program? Would you be interested in having a bonus for a shorter program? For example, lowest total score wins, with score made up of compressed size/original size + log2(number of characters in program). I don't think this is needed - just wondering.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I was thinking about that... but probably not. Maybe this time we judge purely on compression ratio, then we do a [tag:code-golf] for the shortest implementation of the winning algorithm.

Comment: Yes separating the two does sound better. Good thinking.

Comment: This looks to me suspiciously like "Write a wrapper about bzip2". Given that you're asking us to compress a format which has many equivalent ways of writing the same thing (lots of optional whitespace, optional ordering of attributes, flexibility in the quoting characters used, etc.) it would make a more interesting question to require that the decompressed file be semantically equivalent to the input. It makes testing it harder, but it allows for a lot more ingenuity.

Comment: As a separate matter, if you're asking us to compress XHTML by using our knowledge of its structure, you should be more specific about which structure we can assume. XHTML has at least 6 versions, and arguably more: which of them must be supported?

Comment: @PeterTaylor That might be a problem, I tried the http://validator.w3.org, even the Google homepage (supposedly respectable) gets 23 errors...

Comment: @PeterTaylor XHTML 1.0 Transitional?
I personally find XHTML 1.0 Strict *a bit* annoying...

Comment: I don't really care which you pick: just that you make it clear in the question.

Comment: can anyone suggest a test text?

Answer (score 0):

(this isn't quite a duplicate of [Water-Bucket problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5409/water-bucket-problem) because that question was ill-posed and apparently abandoned; it's also not a duplicate of [3 and 5 Litre Jug Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20754/3-and-5-litre-jug-puzzle) because that one was just a single instance, and an instance of a different problem to boot)

## die-harder

***THE PROBLEM***

In commemoration of [Leslie Lamport's Turing Award](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/lamport-031814.aspx), let's borrow a
problem from his [TLA+ online hyperbook](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/tla/hyperbook.html).  There are two versions:
"Die Hard" and "Die Harder." "Die Hard" is an instance of the general,
"Die Harder" problem. "Die Hard" is the following:

Given an empty jug, `jug[0]`, with capacity 3 gallons; and an empty jug,
`jug[1]`, with capacity 5 gallons, deliver exactly 4 gallons of water
under the following rules; you may:

1. fill a jug completely, making its current amount equal to its capacity
2. spill a jug completely, making its current amount equal to zero
3. pour into a jug from another, either filling the destination, emptying the source, or both

One solution is to

1. fill jug 1 (amounts are 0, 5)
2. pour jug 1 into jug 0 (amounts are 3, 2)
3. spill jug 0 (amounts are 0, 2)
4. pour jug 1 into jug 0 (amounts are 2, 0)
5. fill jug 1 (amounts are 3, 4)
6. spill jug 0 (amounts are 0, 4)

I believe there are 3 more.

"Die Harder" is the following:

Given an ordered collection of `n` empty jugs with non-zero,
not-necessarily unique capacities `c[0], c[1], ..., c[n-1]`, deliver
exactly `k` gallons of water, which may be spread out over multiple
jugs, under the same rules as above.

***THE CHALLENGE***

Beat my [reference Clojure code code](https://github.com/rebcabin/codeGolf/tree/master/die-harder) for

A: performance, by choice of algorithm or by optimization or both (my
algorithm becomes intolerably slow when the number of jugs > 3)

B: clarity (no obfuscators; we want to see your algorithm)

C: elegance

D: brevity

The above expresses the priority of the judging criteria: perf is more
important that clarity, which is more important than elegance, which is
more important than brevity.

Your code should behave as follows:

Given `n`, capacities in the form of a bracketed list like `[3 5 7]` and
a target amount `k`, print `t` solutions in a form like the following in
Clojure syntax, which is a solution for `n = 2`, `capacities = [3 5]`,
`k = 4`, and `t = 2`:

```
({:states
  [{:amount 0, :capacity 3, :id 0} {:amount 4, :capacity 5, :id 1}],
  :trace
  [(fill-jug 0)        (fill-jug 1)       (spill-jug 0)
   (pour-from 0 1)     (spill-jug 0)      (pour-from 0 1)
   (fill-jug 1)        (pour-from 0 1)    (spill-jug 0) ] }
 {:states
  [{:amount 3, :capacity 3, :id 0} {:amount 1, :capacity 5, :id 1}],
  :trace
  [(fill-jug 0)       (pour-from 1 0)     (fill-jug 0)
   (pour-from 1 0)    (spill-jug 1)       (pour-from 1 0)
   (fill-jug 0) ] } )
```

Each of your `t` solutions must present the final states of the jugs and
a sequence of moves, in order, that achieve the solution. Minor
variations to the above format are ok.

Extra credit if your code produces optimal (shortest number of moves,
fewest pours, etc.) solutions and you can prove so. You may present
proofs in commentary with your code; acceptance of a proof is at our
sole discretion, as is judgment of clarity and elegance.

Include instructions for running your code if it's non-obvious (as in,
"how exactly do I run this bit of INTERCAL?").

***OBSERVATIONS***

If the gcd of the capacities does not divide the target amount, the
problem has no solution. In your golf, you might check this (my
reference code assumes it, instead).

Certain moves, while legal, are trivial, namely:

1. filling a full jug
2. spilling an empty jug
3. pouring from an empty jug
4. pouring into a full jug
5. repeating the last move, whatever it was

In your golf, you may either check for these trivial moves or not.

You might unit-test your code on inputs like the following:

```
capacities = [3 5 7],    k = any integer from 0 through 15
capacities = [3 5 7 11], k = any integer from 0 through 26
```

***A REFERENCE SOLUTION***

You can find a [reference solution in Clojure here](https://github.com/rebcabin/codeGolf/tree/master/die-harder). It includes unit
tests that demonstrate the program at work.

### License

Copyright © 2014 die-harder

Distributed under the Eclipse Public License either version 1.0 or (at
your option) any later version.

Comment: What's the scoring system? What's the licence supposed to cover? How much flexibility is supposed to be implied by "*in a form like the following in Clojure syntax*"?

Comment: Great questions. Will revise.

Comment: In your example Die Hard solution, I'm thinking you made a mistake in step 5 - wouldn't the amounts become `2, 5`?

Comment: I've got two solutions for Die Hard showing -- in the first one, after the fifth step, namely (spill-jug 0), the 3-jug (jug 0) has 0 and the 5-jug (jug 1) has 2. In the second solution, after the fifth step, namely (spill-jug 1), the 3-jug (jug 0) has 1 and the 5-jug (jug 1) has 0.  Not sure where you're seeing my error :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have not put substantial effort into this sandbox post. Since I am
>   unsure(and it's probably not) whether this kind of question is a good
>   fit for this site or not. If somebody reputable mentions that the idea
>   has merit, I'll tune this sandbox up, and try to get it in shape for
>   posting.
>
> Obviously the biggest problem is how do you test the code? And that's
>   the part I'm stuck on. If anyone can think of a way to overcome this
>   please let me know! Anyway, here it is:

Write a program that posts itself as an answer

Your program must establish an http connection to codegolf.stackexchange.com, login, and post an answer to this question.

The answer must be in the form of:

"

### [Language]

```
Code
```

"

Rules: Cannot read source file, or any resource which is identical to your source file in any way.

Tags: popularity contest, quine

Comment: Imagine what would happen if people try to test each answer!

Comment: How about posting the source code to the *About Me* section of your PP&CG profile page instead? If email addresses and passwords etc. are provided as external input, then it would be easier to test other people's code and we wouldn't have to worry about giving away our login details. However, there could be problems with people using different login methods. For example, I sign in with my Google account. That may not be the most efficient method for a golfed solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Create an Andy Warhol portrait

[Andy Warhol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Warhol) was one of the main figures of the Pop Art. One of his most famous works was a Marylin Monroe picture in nine frames changing the colors, saturation and others aspects of a original pic.

[image: Warhol work]

The challenge here is to create a program that takes any photo and emulates the Warhol painting with some caveats:

1. Final image should be compossed of 9 different frames.
2. Final image will be compossed from 3 rows and 3 columns.
3. Final image should be sized 3 times width and 3 times height of the original image.
4. The program should output just one image.
5. The image that the program outputs must be an emulation of Warhol works.
6. You cannot use any built in function that doest by itself the *Warholization* of the picture neither load or use any external image other than the original. You can use your language methods for changing color, hue, saturation..
7. Program should be deterministic: Any given photo should output the same image every time.

The program should read the image in JPG, BPM or PNG (at your convenience) and output the image in the same format.

The program will be tested with these images:

[image: Marilyn Original]
[image: Campbell soup original]

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) so the most upvoted answers will win. Nobody restrains you from adding more *warholized* pictures for winning more votes from the judges.

Comment: Where do you draw the line for a "built-in function that does the Warholization"? Are functions allowed that can adjust the hue of a pixel/an image? Or the saturation? Or the contrast? Neither of those is a function "to do Warholization", but of course they would probably take care of a large chunk of the work.

Comment: @m.buettner I would say you can use a set of functions that perform the task. If your language have functions to change hue, color, saturation you use them. You cannot use any function that does by itself the warholization (eg some external library or graphic editing program script calling a program built in action...)

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying (maybe add that to the question, that you really mean *only* functions that literally do the Warholization themselves).

Comment: @m.buettner Nice. I will add it to the specs. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be close to a duplicate of [Minature faking](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26317/miniature-faking). It replaces the blur with repetition, but that aside they both seem to just be about simple transformations in HSV space.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

> Kyle is in kindergarten.  He can tie his shoes and count by twos and write in almost every programming language existent!  But he can't seem to remember the days of the week.  They always get mixed up in his mind.
>
> So, his problem is that needs to know what day of the week it is tomorrow.  He decides to write a program for himself.
>
> But, his source code is stored in a very stingy cloud service.  They charge $1.99 per character!  So, he decided to [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) it all...

---

**Challenge**

So, Kyle has hired you for a whopping 15 reputation!  Your challenge is, given the name of a day of the week (`thursday`, for example), you output the name of the next day (`friday`).  The code with the least characters wins.

- The input and output can be in any reasonable method you like (`STDIN`/`STDOUT`, command-line, read from a file, anything).
- You are free to use any built-in function you like.  As long as they don't do *all* the work for you (that's no fun).
- The input and output should be in lowercase.  Kyle hasn't learned about capital letters yet.
- In case you don't know, the weekdays are: `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`, `sunday`.  And they loop around. :-)

Good luck, and may the best code win!

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

---

**Commentary**

I have seen a lot of weekday-related posts here on codegolf.SE, but I am pretty sure that this one will present a unique challenge.

I don't know if the "Preface" is too goofy.  Please comment with your input and I will act accordingly with popular opinion.

Any input or suggestions or comments or upvotes are appreciated!

Comment: does "give me the string representation of n.1.2000 in the format 'full week name'" count as "all the work"? Because the rest is easy.

Comment: Also you forgot Sunday.

Comment: I'm not sure about presenting a unique *challenge*. This can be done in GolfScript with literally 5 chars plus a lookup table. The only interesting part is compressing the lookup table.

Comment: It could be done in bash using `time` and adding a day, then specifying output format.

Comment: @m.buettner : Duh on me.  I guess maybe the problem isn't complex/long enough.  Probably won't go live.

Answer (score 0):

## Brute Force Decryption

### The Task

Write an function `B()` in any language of your choice that takes an encrypted string as input and brute forces though solutions then infers the key used. Your program should then output the decrypted string and the key.

The encrypted string is one that is in English, is a valid sentence and has been encrypted by shifting the ASCII number by the key.

### The Rules

- This is code golf, smallest program wins.
- You can’t use any external dictionaries.

### Encryption

To help you along I’ve written this program, which shows you how the string is encrypted:

```
def encrypt(string, key):
    encrypted = str()
    for Char in string:
        encrypted += (chr(ord(Char) + key))
    return encrypted

def decrypt(string, key):
    decrypted = str()
    for Char in string:
        decrypted += (chr(ord(Char) - key))
    return decrypted
```

Use Like:

```
>>> encrypt("secret", 5)
'xjhwjy'
>>> decrypt("xjhwjy", 5)
'secret'
```

Comment: This has pretty much been done already: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24739/11006

Comment: Oh, yep, couldn't find that one, never mind!

Answer (score 0):

**GCD Game for better algorithm**

Given A,B print the number of pairs (a,b) such that GCD(a,b)=1 and 1<=a<=A and 1<=b<=B.

Input:

First line contains T, the number of testcases. Each testcase consists of two space separated integers denoting A and B.

Output:

The Number of pairs which have GCD=1

Constraints:

- 1 <= T <= 10
- 1 <= A <= 10<sup>5</sup>
- 1 <= B <= 10<sup>5</sup>

Sample Input

```
1
3 2
```

Sample Output

```
5
```

Explanation

There are five pairs of relatively prime numbers (where the first <= 3 and the second <= 2):

1,1
1,2
2,1
3,1
3,2

Time Limit 5 sec(s)

Memory Limit 256 MB

Source Limit 1024 KB

Use smart ways **Bruteforce won't work.**

Comment: Okay, this is a start! So what's the objective winning criterion? Execution time of the program? In that case,on which benchmark and on which machine? Or code size?

Comment: If there are multiple testcases (T>1), should there be multiple numbers outputted?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you just looking for *an* answer, or are you trying to make a *competition* out of it? I ask because the general feel of the spec makes me feel this was copied/pasted here from an exercise/task/homework, not intended as a competition. I ask because if you're just trying to figure out *how to do it*, another SE site might be a better choice for this. If it *is* a competetion, you should add winning criteria as m.buettner noted.

Comment: @Ypnypn if there is multiple test cases multiple outputs will be there

Comment: @m.buettner Wining criteria is the most optimised code(optimised algorithm) which executes fastest

Comment: @user3680169 as it stand that is not objective. do you want to judge that by actual execution time or by asymptotic complexity of the algorithm? in the former case, how is execution time measured, in the latter case, what about ties?

Comment: @m.buettner asymptotic complexity of the algorithm

Comment: @user3680169 how are ties broken? It's not unlikely that two or more answers will have the same complexity.

Comment: The question should reference OEIS [A135646](http://oeis.org/A135646). It should also clarify the output format in the case that there's more than one test case. Also beware that questions involving primality tend to get tricky enough to analyse for asymptotic performance that some people will either not answer because they can't analyse their own program, will answer without the analysis and expect you to do it for them, or will give an unnecessarily loose complexity bound.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Code Looking For 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x76, and 0x65 In All the Wrong Places

Write the shortest code that finds all instances of love" on the system. For this challenge love shall be defined as the bytes 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x76, and 0x65 in sequential order.  It should look for love within files, in memory, and in file names.  The code should run on Ubuntu to be tested.  Assume you have whatever access you need to perform these operations.

**Winning Criteria**

The code will be run under a Ubuntu 12.04 instance that is hosted on a dual boot Windows 8.1 machine.  There will be 1 file on each of the hard drives named love.  The grub loader has a configuration called love.  A program will be running in the background.  If you find all the instances and have the shortest code.  You will win.  The contest will close XX/XX/YYYY.

Comment: What's the winning criterion? How do you even test that submissions actually do find *every single occurrence* of his byte sequence?

Comment: Will this question be open in a browser, and hence held in memory, when you run the programs? Will the rival programs all be present on your machine while they are being run? I guess at least some of them will contain `love`...

Comment: What does it mean to "find" it? Does a memory/file/offset location need to be output for each one?

Comment: That's a really good call out.  I will have to think a little.

Answer (score 0):

## Factorize any number using a set of predetermined *random* numbers

For instance:

With the randomly generated set `[1,2,3,5,8]`, factorizing `10` would give the result `[2,5]` as in `2*5=10`.

- If a number can not be factorized using the provided set, indicate
  so. Using the same set, factorizing `13` would show an error or an
  empty list.
- Generated sets should contain less than 64 numbers.

## Bonuses

The score is given by `floor (code length * (1 - 0,1 * # of bonuses))`

- If a number can not be factorized, try to fix it using addition. In
  the previous example, factorizing `13` could give `[2,5]` and `[3]`
  as in `2*5+3=13`.
- If a number can not be factorized, try to fix it using subtraction. In
  the previous example, factorizing `14` could give `[3,5]` and `[1]`
  as in `3*5-1=14`.
- When generating a set, filter out primes and powers of 2.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Comment: If posted like this, I would vote to close as not clear what you're asking. At the very least you need to specify what the input and output are. Then either ditch the bonuses or make them clearer: what exactly does "*fix it using addition*" mean? E.g. with `[2,3] 17` do we get `2*2*3+2+3`?

Comment: Test comment, ignore. [tag:math]

Answer (score 0):

## Find the a Strong Prime

What's a String Prime? Wikipedia:

> In cryptography, a prime number p is strong if the following conditions are satisfied.[1]
>
> - `p` is sufficiently large to be useful in cryptography; typically this requires `p` to be too large for plausible computational resources to enable a cryptanalyst to factorise products of `p` multiplied by other strong primes.
> - `p-1` has large prime factors. That is, `p = a_1 q_1 + 1` for some integer `a_1` and large prime `q_1`.
> - `q_1-1` has large prime factors. That is, `q_1 = a_2 q_2 + 1` for some integer `a_2` and large prime `q_2`.
> - `p+1` has large prime factors. That is, `p = a_3 q_3 - 1` for some integer `a_3` and large prime `q_3`.

### Input

Your program must receive a number of bits `16 <= x <= 60`. This can be a method definition, command line argument, or stdin.

### Output

Print and/or return a strong prime of exactly the given bit length.

### Other rules:

- All variables in the below conditions refer to the wikipedia variables.
- Do not worry about condition 1 from wikipedia.
- For the rest of these rules, the notation `|x|` means the number of bits in `x`.
- `|q_2| >= 0.4 |p|`.
- You may not use any external tools. Other input data or precalculation counts against the length of your program even if it's in a different file or command line.
- You are allowed (and even encouraged) to [use the algorithms in this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS01.version-1999-11-22.pdf) (thanks @PeterTaylor!) but it is not a requirement.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

Comment: Three things. 1. 10 minutes is probably not enough for even good implementations of basic sieves. Are you expecting people to implement sophisticated sieves, or did you intend to allow probabilistic primality testing? 2. Why the "no more than 3 bits" constraints? There are plenty of definitions going around, but from cursory reading it seems that most of them would consider `|q_2| >= 0.4 |p|` to be sufficient. 3. Have you done a reference implementation to test that strong primes by your definition are sufficiently frequent for the time constraint to be feasible?

Comment: In my above comment, `||` should be taken to mean length in bits rather than absolute value.

Comment: @PeterTaylor how's that?

Comment: Is "*other external tools*" meant to include `IsPrime` functions?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes. but maybe that's not a good rule in this case?

Comment: Probably needs some input from Mathematica users, or you risk creating a restriction which they can waltz straight past.

Comment: [According to the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A014233), Miller-Rabin can be relied on to give accurate results for numbers up to at least 2^61 when tested with the first 9 prime numbers (i.e., a(9)>2^61). If the limit for p is extended to 2^64, then the first 12 primes will have to be tested. This shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

## Saving Eve

### Background

In the year 1946 the organisation *Illuminati* launched their first intelligence collecting satellite - called *Eve* - into orbit around the earth. Onboard it contains a highly sophisticated set of sensors capable of eavesdropping on every telephone call in the world. All suspicious calls are recorded along with all ascertainable information about the caller and receiver. Eve then relays everything to Illuminati's office in Venice.

However, recently the growing amount of radio communication in space and on earth has started to interfere with Eve's downlink and uplink to and from the Venice office, which has resulted in spurious intermixing of the recordings of suspicious calls with the local weather report.

`...we are to drop the bomb ... ...sunny and 28 degrees! In fair Verona... ...shoot them down...`

Seeing as this interferes with Illuminati's ability to control all governments of the world, the error correction encoding firmware of Eve must be upgraded.

### Objective

You have been hired to write the new firmware for Eve. You have realised that the only sufficiently robust and efficient encoding is to use the extended binary Golay code, which encodes 12-bits into 24-bits of data. Luckily Eve was built in the 40's, before the 8-bit byte convention, so all the data that Eve processes is already in 12-bit chunks.

So you have to write a function or a program that takes one 12-bit chunk (as an integer) and outputs or returns a 24-bit chunk (again as an integer) according to the extended binary Golay code.

And you have to write a decoding function or program that takes one 24-bit chunk (again as a an integer) and outputs the decoded 12-bits, with a 16th bit set (2^15) if any correctable errors were detected, and a 20th bit set (2^19) if any uncorrectable errors were detected.

But since the uplink to Eve is unstable you must write the functions or programs in the least amount of characters possible, so that it takes a minimal amount of time to upload.

### Winning criteria

The least amount of characters in the source code of the encoding and decoding functions or programs.

### Note

The exact details of the output of the encoding is not that important, as long as the solution can correct any error up to 3 bits and detect any error up to 7 bits.

Comment: Could do with a link to a good description of the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Meta Code-golf [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Golfing code can be slightly annoying<sup>[*citation needed*]</sup>. There are some things that can be automatically be applied to every golfing problem (e. g. remove all newlines). So what do you do? Automate it!

Your task is to write a program that will golf another program. Naturally, your program must be also be golfed, otherwise this wouldn't be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question, would it?

The following rules apply to your program:

- All the code must be in one file, except for that of the program your program is golfing.
- You may assume that the code of the program to be golfed is contained in a string. That string will not be counted towards your score.
- The output of the golfed program must be identical to that of the original program.
- Your program need only golf programs in it's own language. For example, a Python code-golfer-bot-thing need only successfully golf Python code, it can break all the Java code it wants.

*Sandbox note: I'm not sure how to score this. The length of the golfer should be factored in, as should the difference between an ungolfed and golfed program. I'm thinking something like `(ungolfed - golfed) / chars in answer`, but this would require a way of finding the average number of characters removed. This suggests something of a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), with random programs being chosen and passed to the bots to be golfed, but I would probably have to limit that to Python because that's to only language for which I have a bunch of random programs lying around on my box. However, I have no idea how to implement this and I don't want to spend a while looking through 100+ programs looking for sensitive information (passwords, email addresses, names). Anyway, in this case, score would probably be `(average ungolfed - golfed) / chars in answer`. Any thoughts? Side note to the sandbox note: sorry for the convoluted state of the note. I was basically just vomiting all my thoughts onto the page as they came to me.*

Comment: [There's an entire tag for that](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf). Are you sure your challenge adds anything new to this?

Comment: Essentially this idea has been proposed twice on the sandbox, and neither time has it prospered. It's very hard to write a good spec for it. I suggest that you look through the old sandboxes for the previous versions and read their comment threads.

Answer (score 0):

## Reve's puzzle

From [The Canterbury Puzzles](http://djm.cc/library/The_Canterbury_Puzzles_Dudeney_edited.pdf):

> When the pilgrims were stopping at a wayside tavern, a number of
>   cheeses of varying sizes caught his alert eye; and calling for four
>   stools, he told the company that he would show them a puzzle of his
>   own that would keep them amused during their rest.  He then placed n
>   cheeses of graduating sizes on one of the end stools, the smallest
>   cheese being at the top (and no cheese resting on a smaller one.)
>   'This is the riddle', quoth he, 'that I did once set before my fellow
>   townsmen at Baldeswell, that is in Norfolk, and, by Saint Joce, there
>   was no man among them that could rede it aright. And yet it is withal
>   fully easy, for all that I do desire is that, by the moving of one
>   cheese at a time from one stool unto another, ye shall remove all the
>   cheeses to the stool at the other end without ever putting any cheese
>   on one that is smaller than itself. To him that will perform this feat
>   in the least moves that be possible will I give a draught of the best
>   that our good host can provide.'

Write a function called `reve` that takes five arguments — the number of cheeses n >= 0 and labels for four stools (the source, two intermediaries, and the destination) — and outputs the minimum set of moves necessary to solve Reve's puzzle.

For example, the original puzzle is posed with n = 8, 10, and 21 cheeses, so running `reve 8 "A" "B" "C" "D"` should return the following 33 moves:

```
[("A","C"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("C","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","A"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("A","D")]
```

`reve 10 "A" "B" "C" "D"` (49 moves)

```
[("A","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("C","A"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","D")]
```

`reve 21 "A" "B" "C" "D"` (321 moves)

```
[("A","C"),("A","D"),("A","B"),("D","B"),("C","B"),("A","D"),("A","C"),("D","C"),("A","D"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("A","D"),("B","A"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("C","D"),("A","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("A","B"),("C","A"),("C","B"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("B","A"),("C","A"),("B","C"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","B"),("D","C"),("D","A"),("C","A"),("B","A"),("D","C"),("D","B"),("C","B"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("A","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("C","B"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("C","A"),("C","B"),("A","B"),("C","A"),("B","C"),("B","A"),("C","A"),("D","C"),("D","B"),("D","A"),("B","A"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("C","D"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("D","C"),("B","C"),("D","B"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("A","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","A"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("C","D"),("A","D"),("B","C"),("B","A"),("C","A"),("B","C"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","B"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("C","B"),("A","B"),("D","B"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("A","D"),("C","A"),("D","C"),("D","A"),("C","A"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("C","A"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("D","B"),("C","B"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("D","C"),("D","B"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("A","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("A","B"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("D","A"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("C","A"),("C","D"),("C","B"),("D","B"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("D","A"),("D","C"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("C","A"),("D","A"),("C","D"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("B","A"),("D","A"),("C","A"),("B","D"),("B","C"),("D","C"),("B","D"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("B","D"),("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("C","D"),("B","D")]
```

An up vote for all successful attempts. Shortest solution by character count wins. Sorry, no beer. Although if you're ever in the Boston area, it's on me.

#### Questions

- Is this a suitable question for code golf?
- Is it clear what I'm asking? Do I need to be more specific about input/output, etc.?
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Tower of Hanoi Solver](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/tower-of-hanoi-solver)?

Comment: @Rusher The only difference between this and the Tower of Hanoi is that this uses 4 stacks instead of 3. I'm not sure that's enough different, though it would defeat most Tower of Hanoi solutions, which are typically recursive, while this seems more brute-force.

Comment: The input/output spec is certainly unclear. You ask for a function, and then give examples of program invocation. The other thing which isn't clear is whether you want "pure" code golf (ignoring realistic feasibility assumptions) or whether you want a program which can actually execute for 21 discs with only e.g. 2GB of RAM, explicitly using disk as a backing store.

Comment: I think the T(4,n) case of Tower of Hanoi is sufficiently different from T(3,n) and is the subject of many interesting papers. This does not require brute force. Frame-Stewart will solve this recursively, though it is still an open question whether the algorithm is optimal for all values of n and k in T(n,k). There are several papers that have popped on arXiv in the last few years that argue Frame-Stewart is optimal for T(4,k).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree the input/output is unclear. Any suggestions on improving this? I wrote my solver in Haskell, hence the term 'function' and the lack of commas/parentheses for invocation. I'm fairly certain this is feasible — my function works and it will spit out `reve 100 "A" "B" "C" "D"` with little fuss (172033 moves). Perhaps I have made some mistake in my implementation? I can post the code if you would like to test. Regardless, I think this is a **really** interesting problem. Yes, it is 'just' Tower of Hanoi with 4 pegs, but a solution — let alone an optimal one — isn't obvious.

Comment: It's an interesting problem, yes, but mainly because it's not clear that Frame-Stewart is optimal. The well-known 3-tower implementation is a special case of Frame-Stewart, and a fully general implementation isn't much more interesting. If we can assume optimality of Frame-Stewart, then I would vote to close as duplicate of the 3-tower question. If we can't, issues of performance (or of its irrelevance) need addressing.

Comment: Understood. I guess it should be closed then.

Answer (score 0):

## Type me out.

Your task (related to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32654/9534)) is to translate any text (in a file, or simply input) into the input of a telephone keypad.

[image]

and provide a keypress score.

As the keypad has a limited set of keys you have to 'encode' your non-alphanumerics with their ASCii hexadecimal encoding; e.g. to type ~ (which is hexidecimal ASCII land is 7e) you press the hash key once, the 7 key (once to get a seven) and then 3 three times to cycle through the digits 3, 'd', and finally 'e'. This gives the code #7e which corresponds to ~ (for a total number of key presses of 5). Spaces and capitals have to be accessed via hex code (so MY_CONST (`#4d #59 #53def #43 #4f #4e #53 #54` - 27 presses) costs you less than my_const (`6m 9wxy #53def 2bc 6mno 6mn 7pqrs 8t` - 29), but more than myconst  (`6m 9wxy 2bc 6mno 6mn 7pqrs 8t` - 23)).

> For instance If your code had `print()` that would cost 15 for the print
>   (7p 7pqr 4ghi 6mn 8t) plus 6 for the () (#28 #29)

To be clear with just the input  `print()` the output is:

```
7p 7pqr 4ghi 6mn 8t #28 #29
21
```

(Note however the hex codes for `c f i r s v y z` are shorter (correspondingly `#63 #66 #69 #72 #73 #76 #79 #7a`) than long hand key presses. It's perfectly allowed to score `print()` as 19:

```
7p #72 #69 6mn 8t #28 #29
19
```

)

This is Code Golf, so feed your code into the finished program - shortest answer (in keypresses) wins.

Comment: Migrated from previous sandbox

Comment: So we enter 'print()' as our input and the output is the second code block? and our answer needs to be processed by the program we wrote, and the shorted processed answer wins? 2 questions: 1) is ~ 3 or 5 characters? because we need to press 3 three times. 2) is our score the bytelength or the keypress score?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs 1) it's 5 2) it's key presses.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm posting here first so I don't clutter up the site in case people are tired of pi questions. Thoughts?

## Yet Another Pi Question

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Today (actually tomorrow as I post this) is Pi Approximation Day (22/7), so here is a variant of the "compute pi" golf that I don't think has been seen before.

**Write a program that accepts a number, either on standard input or as a command line argument, and prints that many digits of pi to standard output.**

Details, for the nitpicky:

- You may write the program to accept its input as the ASCII characters representing the number of digits, in either decimal or hexadecimal (preceded by `0x`), or as a sequence of bytes representing that value. For example, if I want to tell your program to compute 65535 digits of pi, I would invoke it in your choice of one of the following six ways (using bash syntax):

  ```
  program 65535
  program 0xffff
  program $'\xff\xff'
  echo 65535 | program
  echo 0xffff | program
  echo $'\xff\xff' | program
  ```
- The program must produce no output on standard output other than the required decimal digits of pi, and the decimal point. There are no constraints on what it may write to standard error or to any files.
- The leading 3 may count toward your number of digits, or not; your call. (It has to be printed either way.)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) apply, including using a builtin constant to supply the value of pi. (I'm looking at you Mathematica)
- You may assume that the value passed in will be small enough not to exceed resource limits in your program (recursion depth, memory allotment, integer overflow, etc.). Your program should be written in such a way that increasing these resource limits will allow it to compute more digits.

Comment: You might want to do something about a Mathematica answer along the lines of `π~N~n`, where `n` is the input number. ;) That is, you should probably restrict access to built-in π, trigonometric functions, etc.

Comment: Seems similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/506/calculate-500-digits-of-pi

Comment: @KyleKanos that one has some fairly arbitrary restrictions on it, and besides it's about printing a fixed number of digits rather than an arbitrary number. Similar, yes, in the sense that many questions asking some variant of "print pi" are similar, but not the same IMO.

Comment: @MartinBüttner that's one of the standard loopholes but I could make it explicit.

Comment: @DavidZ: I think the general consensus is that if answers can be taken from one question and modified slightly for another, it's a duplicate. I do see the difference between this Q and the one I linked to, I'm just kinda giving heads-up to a good friend that some on this site might not see enough of a difference.

Comment: Yeah, of course I do see your point. I figured I'd put up the suggestion anyway, just in case.

Comment: @DavidZ That is one of the most disputed loopholes though, so it might be worth mentioning it explicitly.

Comment: Calculating pi in decimal has been thoroughly mined, hexadecimal has been done, rational approximation has been done, trig function evaluation has been done. If you're looking for a question which won't be closed as a duplicate then you need to be much more inventive. Perhaps use Euler's evaluation of the Riemann zeta function at positive integers in terms of pi as an excuse to ask a question about numerical evaluation of the non-trivial zeroes of zeta.

Comment: @PeterTaylor of course the specific numerical constant is irrelevant; I could just as well ask the same question for e, or the golden ratio, or a zero of the zeta function, but that wouldn't change whether it's a duplicate or not. I'm getting the sense this whole area of computing numerical constants is overdone.

Comment: Different constants have different formulae available for calculation; the golden ratio admits an extremely short program by virtue of its continued fraction representation (which is probably equivalent to finding it by Newton-Raphson) whereas short formulae for pi use other types of infinite series or product. The interesting thing about pi is how many formulae for it are known, and that might partly be why it has been done to death already.

Answer (score 0):

## Dining Philosophers (Incomplete)

Please do not vote or comment yet.

---

## Introduction

Cooperate with other Philosophers in order to eat your dinner as quickly as possible.

## Game

You will be randomly paired with two other philosophers. Each philosopher begins with one fork. A philosopher needs two forks to eat his dinner. Each round you may take one of six actions:

- Take the fork on your left
- Take the fork on your right
- Place a fork to your left
- Place a fork to your right
- Eat
- Wait

The following behaviors will cause you to wait by default.

- Attempting to take a fork that is not there
- Attempting to place a fork you do not have
- Attempting to eat with less than two forks
- Attempting to take a fork when you are already holding two

Once every philosopher has successfully eaten, the trial is completed. Each participant is scored according to how long it took all three participants to eat.

## Input

Input description here.

For Java submissions, input will be passed via parameter. For non-Java submissions, input will be provided via a command argument.

## Output

Output description here.

## Deliverables

**Java Submissions**

You must submit a unique title and a Java class that extends the abstract Philosopher class written below.

```java
public abstract class Human {
    public abstract String takeAction(String arg);
}
```

**Non-Java Submissions**

You must submit a unique title, a program, and a Windows command line string that will run your program. Remember that an argument may be appended to that string. For example:

- `python Aristotle.py`

  - Note that this one has no args. This is round one! Be prepared for this.
- `python Aristotle.py args`

## Scoring

Your final score will be the median of your scores across ____ trials.

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This challenge might not work out on this site, **please down vote this answer if you feel like it won't work** and up vote if you think it could. If you down vote, a comment would be appreciated. I don't see the point in limiting the freedom of the participants since I think it will make things less fun/interesting.

## Your love you want to show 'em, generate them a poem.

```
Poetry is not easy;
Rhyming is too hard.
Generate me a poem that's not too cheesy.
If it's good enough we'll call it art.
```

In all honesty, poetry really is tough beans. So for this challenge I ask you to write some code in the language of your choice that will generate poetry.

### Restrictions

Your program has to be able to output a large amount of generated poetry of reasonable quality. This means that you can't write code that tries to 'generate' a poem that already exists. You also can't sample parts of existing poetry (this includes poetry invented by you). It is okay if some (or even most) of your code's poems make no sense and there are only a small percentage of good poems. I'm sure that code that consistently generates good poetry will be more popular though. Other than that there are no restrictions, you can use dictionaries, you can use the internet, you can strive for a certain rhyming scheme or several. It's poetry, get creative.

### Your answer

Your answer should include:

- Your full code or a link to it.
- An explanation of your strategy.
- Some of your favorite poems generated by your code.

### The winner

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most votes wins.

### But what's a poem?

I see where you're going with this. You could output a list of words and claim it's poetry. I fear the other users won't be too impressed with that though and you won't get many votes (if you can avoid down votes). However, that doesn't mean it absolutely has to rhyme, there are plenty of ways of making poetry interesting and if you can have your code generate non-rhyming poetry that other people like, you deserve those votes. Explaining your strategy will also help people see why what you did is interesting.

Comment: This seems to be a bit too broad. What classifies as "poetry" for this challenge? Poetry doesn't necessarily need to rhyme, or follow any form or rhythm. I could claim for almost any text that it's poetry of some weird abstract form. You might want to place some restrictions on that. Also, if you're disallowing sampling parts of existing poetry, does that mean I can't submit a solution which just fills in blanks in a fixed structure or randomly combines a predetermined set of lines? Where do you draw the line between sampling a dictionary and sampling existing poetry?

Comment: @Martin I would say that taking combinations of words from existing poetry is sampling, filling in a structure wouldn't be. As for it being too broad, I feel like making it less broad would make the challenge less fun. Since the quality of the output is subjective, should we really be putting strict restrictions on what we want as an output? Or is this explicitly against the rules of SE? Maybe the poems should have a minimum length though.

Comment: It's not necessarily *against the rules*, but there's a close-vote reason for questions being "too broad", and I could see this being closed as it stands. You'll just get people producing completely random chains of words and claiming that they are poetry.

Comment: @Martin Those should get downvoted though. Poetry is hard to define and I don't want to restrict people's creativity by failing to define it. If people like the output of a program, who's to say it's not poetry?

Comment: I get your point, I'm just saying people are still very likely to close your challenge. The question isn't whether there are too many possible answers which would be upvoted but too many possible *valid* answers. And in fact I even think there might be too many possible answers that could be upvoted. There are just so many different kinds of (more or less weird) poetry.

Comment: Do you think that means the challenge isn't a good challenge or not a good fit for SE?

Comment: It's certainly a very interesting challenge, but as it stands too broad for SE, I think.

Comment: There are many [subclasses of poetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Poetic_form) already well defined. Often a restricted format leads to more creativity, not less (both in writing poetry and in writing code).

Comment: I, for one, find this a perfectly fine challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Program calculating its own length [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Task

Your task is simple: write a program that produces its own length, without using any literals or built-in constants other than `0` (or its equivalents in your language).

### Rules

1. Your code must print its own length in bytes when run, followed by a single newline.
2. Your code cannot use any literals other than `0` (or whatever equivalents your language might have). This includes string and character literals.
3. Your code cannot use any built-in constants of your language, unless these are guaranteed to always have the value `0`.
4. Any functions and operators provided by your language can be used.
5. You're not allowed to use any external libraries or external resources in your program.

### Scoring

The score of a valid program is its length in bytes. The score of an invalid program is ∞.
As this is code golf, lowest score wins.

Comment: Does "any literals" include the more involved ones like function, array and object literals? Apart from this restriction, I'm pretty sure this has been asked before.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Probably a dupe: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/27079/16402

Comment: Would this Python entry be valid (not golfed)? It uses only globals. `text = open(__file__, 'rb').read(); length = len(text); print(length)`

Comment: May we use built-in lists that are guaranteed to be `[]`?

Comment: In Jelly (and likely much more esolangs), a empty program outputs 0, producing an answer that is very hard to beat; [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwQA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### Find a multiple of 42 that is spelled with all of the characters that make up the word "forty-two".

Rules:

1. All of the characters in "forty-two" must be included at least once. Dashes count as characters, and each character must be used *cumulatively* (`dog` doesn't contain all of the characters that make up the word `dogg`, for example).
2. The result can be any multiple of 42 that meets the defined criteria, presented in numerical form.
3. Result must be multiple of greater than 1 (or less than -1). In other words, `42` and `-42` are not allowed.
4. Additional characters not in the word "forty-two" are O.K.
5. The program must calculate its result without utilizing prior knowledge of a multiple known to include the right letters.
   **Clarification:**

   - This means that self trivial solutions such as hard-coding the program to print `42,000` are not allowed.
   - As an exception to this rule, prior knowledge of the maximum result possibility (`42,000`, for example) may be used to define the program's ability to name numbers up to the necessary size.

The shortest code (counting in bytes) to do so in any language wins.

Comment: This was down-voted in the original post, so I've improved it and posted here to see if it might be further improved to the point of liking. It seems to me like a nice challenge.

Comment: I think that the specification are good now and the challenge would be fun, but this seems to be pretty much a duplicate of [Converting integers to English words](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/converting-integers-to-english-words) just with an added loop and comparison. There are some more questions like that here already, which can be found searching for `site:codegolf.stackexchange.com english number`

Comment: @tim perhaps a small creative twist, then?

Answer (score 0):

## Tennis Tournament (Incomplete)

Please do not vote or comment yet.

---

## Introduction

Insert tennis themed introduction here.

## Game

Insert description of the tournament hierarchy, player seeding, and program flow.

## Input

You will be passed the current set of matches. Matches will be comma (`,`) delimited. Players within a match will be dash (`-`) delimited. Players will be represented by ID and strength in the format `<ID>$<Strength>`. Byes will be represented by `0$0`.

Java submissions will be supplied input via argument to the `takeAction()` function. Non-Java submissions will be supplied input via command line argument.

**Example**

The following input represents a three player tournament. The players' IDs are 2, 1, and 3. Their strengths are 1, 2, and 2, respectively. Player 3 has a bye.

> 2$1-1$2,0$0-3$2

## Output

Return the string "play" if you want to play. Return the string "concede" if you want to concede.

## Deliverables

**Java Submissions**

You must submit a unique title and a Java class that extends the abstract Athlete class written below.

```java
public abstract class Athlete {
    public abstract String takeAction(String arg);
}
```

**Non-Java Submissions**

You must submit a unique title, a program, and a Windows command line string that will run your program. Remember that an argument will be appended to that string. For example:

- `python RafaelNadal.py args`

## Scoring

Your final score will be the median of your scores across ____ trials.

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Answer (score 0):

## Teach me to play clarinet

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (might be an optimization problem for [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge))

This is mostly a work in progress until I figure out the best input and output notation/formatting.

---

The clarinet is a very complicated instrument, as there are more keys than I have fingers.  Additionally, there may be multiple ways to play the same note.  I dream of becoming a professional clarinetist one day, but I am very lazy at everything I do.  When playing music, I try to move my fingers as little as possible.*

The input will be a series of musical notes, which each note consisting of a note name (like `E` or `G#`) and a number which represents which octave of the clarinet is being discussed.

Examples:

```
E1 - low E, the bottom note
C1 - C below the staff
E2 - E at the bottom of the staff
F#3 - F# at the top line of the staff
G4 - G that is 4 ledger lines above the staff, the highest note needed
```

An example input might be

```
Eb2 D2 F#3 F3 F#3 G3 F#3
```

From this list of notes, your program should determine which fingerings I should use to play these notes in the easiest way possible.  "Easiest" means that the total number of finger movements should be minimized (how to explain?).

The output should describe my finger position for each note in terms of the location of each of my fingers.

---

One problem I see is that there is no standardized fingering chart for clarinet.  Furthermore, no fingering charts actually specify which fingers are used to play which keys.  One thing I would have to do is create a list of all possible positions for each finger.  Then, a single fingering "diagram" would consist of the list of keys, telling which are open/closed/either.  There would be multiple fingering diagrams for each note.

The next problem is that the number of distinct fingerings can grow to be quite large when certain tricks are taken into account such as "leaving the right hand down while playing throat tones."  This would be the reason for adding the "either" option to the fingering charts.

I must figure out how to notate the fingering charts and format the output.

---

*this is actually a good thing and not lazy

Comment: As for the fingering charts, my clarinet book has a chart labeling each key with a character, A-Q, I think.  The holes could be 1-6.  Would this be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

## Chess: End Game KOTH

### Task

You design a bot that plays the final moves of a chess game against other bots. The chess board will be in the end game stage (relatively few pieces) with either a winning position for white, or a force draw. Points will be scored on the outcome of the game in each board situation. Bots will play both the black and white sides for each position (10 unique positions, 20 games in total).

### Rules

1. Basic chess rules apply

   - No [*en passant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) will be possible
   - [Promotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(chess)) of pawns is valid
   - Previous [castling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling) moves will be indicated during board setup, otherwise castling is possible if legal
   - [50 move](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule) rule will apply
   - [Threefold repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_repetition) rule will apply
2. No outside help whatsoever (chess engines, endgame tablebases, stored patterns)
3. Notation will be in the [ICCF numeric notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICCF_numeric_notation) format
4. [Round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) tournament setup (see scoring below)
5. 20 games per match (1 match is one bot-to-bot pairing)

   - Each bot plays 10 games as white and 10 games as black
   - 8 of these games will be force wins for white, the remaining 2 are force draws (but winnable by either player)
   - The same 10 games will be repeated, so each bot will play the same position as both colors.
6. Time limit of 1 minute per match? (*very flexibly here*)

   - Maximum time per move is X seconds (possible [Fischer Delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_control) bonus?)
   - Failure to move in the time limit per move will result in a loss for the current game

### Scoring

*These values will surely change*

```
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| Board Situation     | White Wins | Black Wins | Black Draws | White Draws |
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| Force Win for White | 100        | 500        | 250         | -50         |
| Force Draw          | 250        | 350        | 50          | 50          |
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

1. *Need to figure in number of moves into points*
2. Overall winner is the bot with the most points at the end of the round-robin

### How To Play

1. Controller will be written in python and will communicate to bots via STDIN/STDOUT

   - Bots can be programmed in any language that support persistent polling of STDIN and STDOUT
2. A board will be generated by the controller and sent to both players at the same time (will include information for castling in a TBD format). Each bot will be given ~50 ms to process the board information, but they don't know what side they are playing.
3. Following the short pause, each of the bots will be sent either `B` or `W` character to indicate which side they will play for the next game. At this time, the white bot timer is activated and it can return his move any time afterwards.
4. The bot will response via its STDOUT the move in ICCF numeric notation

> 5453

1. After the move has been validated by the controller, the time remaining for both opponents and the move history will be sent to the each bot, and then the other bot begins their turn. Time will be outputted in ms in the following format `WXXXXX BXXXXX`. The following is the output given to each bot after each [ply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ply_(game_theory)).

> ```
> W54000 B60000 1) 5453
> W54000 B48000 1) 5453 7872
> W52000 B48000 1) 5453 7872 2) 6512
> ```

1. This will repeat (steps 4&5) until the game is won, drawn, or time runs out, after which the bots will be sent the final score of the game and time remaining for the next game of the match

> ```
> W35000 B47000 W+300 B+50
> ```

### Things that might be a problem

1. The efficiency of the language (i.e., C++ vs perl) might bias towards language used instead of algorithm developed
2. Generating board situations (could grab them through an online DB automatically)
3. Too hard/easy to program?

Comment: Do you want to accept or exclude the approach of exhaustively evaluating all future moves? I guess this will affect how long you give per move, and per match (as future moves calculated in the previous turn can be stored and added to on each new turn). For example, if you're near enough to the end of the game that it takes 30 seconds to evaluate all possibilities, then a few moves in a bot could have full knowledge, as some futures will be trimmed by the moves taken so far.

Comment: This won't apply if you choose end games that still have a lot of options open - I don't know if you mean 2 pieces left each or several.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough idea for a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, if possible I would like someone else to help me with it and possibly host the challenge (and consequently getting all of the up votes :] ).

## Pecking Birds - input wanted

You're a bird and birds need to eat. There's not all that much food, so you might need to fight for it.

### Haven't you heard about the bird?

Birds live on a continuous torus where food drops at random places at an increasingly slow rate. They can only see food from a certain distance, they can see all other birds on the torus though. Birds can only move over a limited distance at a time and can peck at either birds, food or nothing within a certain radius. Birds can see a bird's last action, but they can't distinguish between pecks at food and pecks at nothing if they're too far away. Birds that are pecked to death, turn into food. Food disappears after a fixed amount of birds have taken a peck at it. Birds' health goes down every turn, but get refilled a bit if they peck at food.

## Input and Output

If I end up hosting this challenge myself, the controller will be in Java and submissions will be either a java class or a program in another language. Both types of answers will be allowed to persist between turns. Java submissions will have the state of the game copied into global variables and be called to act through a method and send their output as a return value. There will also likely be helper functions available for java submissions. Other submissions will get their info through STDIN and asked to send their output to STDOUT.
There will be two actions every turn, a pecking action and a moving action. before being asked what to do, you will get the position of each bird, their last pecking action and the position and plentitude of all food withing your sight. On your pecking turn you will be asked to either peck at food, peck at a bird, peck at nothing or not peck at all. On the movement turn you will asked to return a position within your movement radius to move to. All birds peck at the same time and then move at the same time alternately. the winner is the last bird standing.

### The competition

Each player will start with 10(?) birds on a `sqrt(n)*50`(?) sized torus, where n is the amount of entries. Your score will be determined by the amount of rounds your last bird died before the last bird standing. Obviously a lower score is better. The simulation will be run several times and some sort of average will be taken to determine the overall winner.

Answer (score 0):

## Tetromino Game [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

#### (name suggestions?)

This game is based off of [L game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_game), an abstract puzzle game by Edward de Bono.

### Rules

Every player is assigned a random position in the list of players. Every round, each player gets a *turn*, in the order defined by the list of players. The game is over once only 1 player remains.

The board is a 2-dimensional grid containing the tetrominoes, as well as 1x1 neutral pieces. It does not wrap. It is generated randomly and all of the pieces are placed on it, with a good amount of neutral pieces (should equal roughly half the amount of empty blocks, and just over 2/3 the total amount of players).

On each turn, the player must move their piece to another position on the board, and optionally a single neutral piece. This can be anywhere, however, no pieces can intersect.

The player loses if they cannot move their tetromino anywhere; they are no longer given any turns, but their tetromino stays.

After 20 rounds, on every round, a neutral piece will be placed randomly on the board.

A player's score is equal to the amount of turns that they have played.

### Submissions

Communication with the controller is done through STDIN and STDOUT. Your submission will run for the entire length of the game. If your program is expected to produce output and doesn't within 4 seconds, you will lose.

At the start of the game, your submission will be launched and you are expected to produce  a tetromino to play with. You should output a number from 0 to 4, corresponding to these tetrominoes:

[image: Tetrominoes]

(modified version of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:All_5_free_tetrominoes.svg))

They are in order of strategical complexity; 4 is the most complex.

Then, the initial game data will be passed to your game.

The first line contains 3 space-separated integers: your position in the list (starting with 0), board width, and board height.

The rest is a rendering of the board: A player's tetromino is made of the last digit of the base-93 number (ascii 33 to 125) of their position in the list. A space is an empty space, and `~` is a neutral piece.

On every turn except your own, your bot will receive information about the turn. The first line can be one of either `M 0 0 0` or `L`; the first is for motion (see next paragraph), and `L` is for that player being unable to make any moves and losing.

The motion line is in the format `M x y r f`, where x and y is the new position of the upper-left block in the bounding box of that player's tetromino, and r is the amount of rotation (0 for 0 degrees, 1 for 90, 2 for 180, 3 for 270, clockwise).

`f` is either 0 or 1; 1 if the player flipped their piece along the x axis (this happens before rotation). Optionally `x y x y` could also be on the end of the line, the first pair of coords being that of a neutral piece, and the next being its target location. It is followed by the new board.

On your turn, `GO` will be given to you on STDIN and you will be expected to produce a string `x y r f` and optionally `x y x y`, similar to the one in the paragraphs just above this. The controller will evaluate whether or not there are possible moves for you just before your turn, and will eliminate you automatically if necessary.

If your output is invalid, you will receive `ERROR` on STDIN and you will be expected to produce a new output. If this happens 5 times in a row, you lose.

Submissions are allowed to store data in files, and initial data for the file can be included with the submission.

### Scoring

Each player's score is equal to the amount of turns they play; however the submission's final score is the sum of all their scores in multiple trials. Trials will be run until the leading submission is 5 points away from the runner-up.

### Name?

Ideas: "Tetromeano" (suggested as a joke on chat), "Space Tetris".

[Discuss the game here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16435/tetromino-game)

Answer (score 0):

### Jenga code

I think everyone knows what [Jenga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenga) is.

As per Wikipedia:

> Jenga is a game of physical and mental skill [...] During the game, players take turns removing one block at a time from a tower constructed of 54 blocks. Each block removed is then balanced on top of the tower, creating a progressively taller but less stable structure.

[image]

**Challenge**

Write a program that behaves as a Jenga tower. Every time a randomly chosen piece of code is removed and placed at the bottom of your program, the code should re-run. Goal is to achieve the tallest running code tower.

**Rules**

- The starting tower (or source code) must be of exactly 15 lines of code. Such lines must be divisible by 3 forming a `15x3n` grid composed by 15 lines of `1xn` bricks.
- A brick is removed randomly from the code and placed at the bottom from left to right until the `3n` block line is complete. The process goes on at the bottom of the new formed line.
- If a brick has strictly more consecutive whitespaces than any consecutive characters in it its considered broken and fails to sustain the tower.
- A brick must always be present for each row (2 holes and 1 brick), but its position in the row is not important.
- A tower is tall 20 lines if the 20th line tower runs with no errors.
- A brick cannot start nor end with comment start or end tags of your chosen language (e.g `/*` or `//`)

**Output**

Each tower must output its own height.

**Scoring system**

Your score is simply the avarage tower height for your program:

```
SCORE = (MAX TOWER + MIN TOWER) / 2
```

Where `MIN TOWER` refers to the minimun non-running tower while `MAX TOWER` refers to the maximum running tower.

*(It would be nice if in the answer both towers are shown)*

Proposed tag: [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I think the basic idea is good, but it lacks some definition; you should probably specify that a line has to be more than just a comment and does something related to the rest of the program. What prevents me from declaring a  new variable on every line and then printing a hardcoded string on one line? I'm not sure if thsi idea could work, but it certainly doesn't work like this.

Comment: Maybe the randomly picked rule is also not beneficial. I believe that if people can specify the order in which the lines are picked, they can get more creative.

Comment: Can't understand your point on the comment line. If the middle brick is taken from that line and placed at the bottom, the code shoulnd't work, right? Or you mean that every single brick has/is a comment?

Comment: For the line picking I can add the rule to choose a [integer sequence](https://oeis.org/) of choice and use the sequence to choose the line (starting again from top when end is reached while counting).

Comment: @Narmer What overactor is referring to is that any brick could be `/* my comment */` which could be removed and moved anywhere without breaking the program. But there are other ways. It is trivial to get the maximum score of 50 in many languages by writing 44 bricks of the form `someVariableName = 0;` and one brick of the form `print "I win!"`. (That was overactor's other point in his first comment.) I agree that the idea is interesting but it needs some work.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I see your point now. First is easily avoidable removing comments, but the second one is tough. I'll think for a solution.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using the output. Something like "every compiled tower must output its height".

Comment: In no particular order, I see the following problems. 1. Is "compiled" intended to exclude interpreted languages (in as much as that distinction makes sense nowadays)? 2. The stuff about holes makes no sense to me. In particular, a) there's nothing stopping a brick from containing a hole; b) the number `4` appears from nowhere and doesn't fit with `n`-char bricks. 3. What are `MIN TOWER` and `MAX TOWER` in the scoring? 4. I can easily write code which does absolutely nothing but compiles. E.g. make each brick `for(;;)break;`.

Comment: Edited to match the comments. Ugh, just seen @PeterTaylor comment.

Comment: Making each tower output its height is easy: just make each brick end in a `//` / `#` as appropriate to comment out the remaining bricks on the line. E.g. in GolfScript making each brick `0or)#` would achieve that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor for your last comment, see my edit. Min tower refers to the minimum non compiling tower, while max tower is for the maximum compiling tower. I'll clear that out.

Comment: For the hole part I was trying to avoid trivial solution where a brick is composed by only < 4 chars (and the line by more than 12), making the tower almost "brickless". I'm still trying to figure out how to make that clear, maybe I should change it in a more clear "if a brick has more whitespaces than characters in it its considered broken and fails to sustain the tower"

Comment: And last but not least for compiling I mean "working with no errors, regardless they are compile or runtime". Don't know why I used such a silly word.

Comment: Pretty much any language which can do a cheat quine by reading its own source can do that and print the newline count in one block, and then do nothing useful in all the other blocks, achieving a perfect score. (I can also see how to get a perfect score in GolfScript by counting newlines without reading the source, but that's actually an interesting answer. OTOH it does mean that the question would be pretty much killed once someone posts it).

Comment: I think that's unavoidable. A single block has to have the possibilty to live on its own, otherwise a single brick line in not possible. I think I have to exploit again the output to alter the program code. Maybe instead of simply the height the program should output an ascii representation of the tower, with XXX for brick and void for hole. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Narmer That seems close to impossible since it will be very hard to determine where the hole is if there are only two bricks left in a row (without reading your own source code).

Comment: Close to impossible is not impossible, and this is a challenge so... jokes aside, that was my fear the entire time while creating the question. Each modification seemed to me to "ruin" with impossibility the question, but in my lurking here in PCG SE you have raised my impossibility limit quite a lot.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I can almost do it in GS. The only problem is that if the first line has a hole before the first brick, there's no chance to assign meaning to the space character before the first one is ignored. That probably doesn't render it impossible, but it is hard. This variant probably makes an interesting challenge for GolfScript users if you add a tie-breaker to the scoring. Not sure how many other languages would be able to do it. A variant on that idea might be to make it so that each tower has to be a true quine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor True, GS and some other languages might be able to do it, but most languages will have it very difficult to get any hint that there is whitespace in the code. I was thinking structuring the bricks such that those spaces end up in a string, but I don't see how to make the code valid for the first and last brick.

Comment: @PeterTaylor and MartinBüttner I can't follow you. Wouldn't the written code imply the number of holes, also for the first line? Also, the challenge doesn't rule that all configuration must work, but asks for the longest working configuration (and the shortest not working)

Answer (score 0):

## Analyze Tonguetwisters  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Your task is to write a program which will accept an English tonguetwister, search for commonly used sounds and decide why it is difficult to pronounce.

1. Calculate the frequency of every sound used in the input sentence.
2. Count identical sounds (for example, `ea` and `ee`) as the same thing.
3. Ignore those sound groups (see below) which occur less than 0.1 times per character of the input.
4. From the sounds that remain, group members of the same group together and separate by a forward slash (`/`).
5. Arrange the groups by decreasing number of occurences.
6. Separate groups by commas.
7. Output.

### Identical Sounds [under construction]

```
ee = ea (in step 2, replace ea by ee)
```

### Sound Groups [under construction]

```
e,ee
s,sh,c,ch
f,th,ph
```

### Examples

Input: `She sells sea-shells on the sea-shore.`

Output: `s/sh,e/ee`

Input: `The seething sea ceaseth and thus the seething sea sufficeth us.`

Output: `s/c,e/ee`

### Rules

- Receive input on STDIN, as command-line arguments or otherwise. You may not expect it to be stored in a variable.
- Output to STDOUT or equivalent.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are banned.

Comment: Are you going to provide a data file which maps words to the pronunciations in a standardised format?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It wasn't in my original plan (which was just to assume that c,sh,s, and ch are always similar, which is not the case as c can be pronounced s or k), but if there is such a file somewhere I can alter the challenge for it to be used

Comment: [An earlier question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24718/194) uses the [CMU Sphinx pronunciation dictionary](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict.0.7a).

Answer (score 0):

## Gun Fight at High Noon

### Gameplay

This will be a 5 or 4 stage (the decision will be explained later) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) tournament where programs are pitched against each other to solve an integration problem faster than the other. The fastest will then go on to the next round.

**Number of rounds:** Due to tournament bracketing, the number of rounds will be decided by the reception of the challenge. For four rounds, sixteen entrants are needed. For five rounds, thirty two entrants are needed.

### The controller

The controller will be written in Python, using time.time() as the timer. When run, it will time one entrant, print the output and time the other entrant and print the output. I will then put the results into a text file and post the results on the question.

### The problem

The problem will be a simple elementary function integration problem with long numbers included. These will be generated randomly when the controller is initiated and both entrants will be given the same problem.

### Rules

1. No inbuilt functions can be used to solve the problems
2. If you fail to calculate the problem correctly, you will lose immediately
3. In event of a tie, the match will be replayed with a different problem

**Inbuilt Functions**

Inbuilt functions include functions that solve integration problems themselves **you must have a hand written integral solving algorithm in your code**.

### Example and Arguments

All information will be transferred via stdout and stdin. The integral will be in the following format:

[Integral http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/3/4/034cf496a9d3026984fcae6cfa58608a.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/3/4/034cf496a9d3026984fcae6cfa58608a.png)

And `f(x)` being like where a and n will be replaced for integers when passed to your program:

[image: f of x]

With arguments being passed like so:

```
programname a b f(x)
```

The reply will be stdout as a floating point integer to a precision of 5 decimal points. An example from one of my tests:

```
~$ python3 showdowncontroller.py Test1 'python3 int1.py' Test2 'python3 int2.py'
A,B:        3,36
Function:   10*x**3
Result:     4199187.88575

Test1: 0.04052305221557617 True 4199187.88575 <- name time correct? output

Test2: 0.04041910171508789 True 4199187.88575


Win: Test2
```

The command run for each program was:

```
python3 [program name].py 3 36 10*x**36
```

And the response was:

```
4199187.88575
```

### Other

In your answer you will need the following:

- Name of your program
- Command to compile your program (if necessary)
- Command to run your program
- Your code
- A short description of your integration method

Your program can be in any language as long as I can compile and run it on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise.

There will be a 0.00005 error tolerance: any more or any less and your program will lose the match. The controller uses [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule).

```python
# Generate numbers
a=random.randint(1, 50)
n=random.randint(1, 10)
b=random.randint(1, 50)
c=random.randint(1, 50)

# Integration using the Simpson method
def integrate(f, a, b):
   h = (b-a)/100
   meth = lambda f,x,h: (f(x) + f(x+h))/2.0
   ival = Decimal(h * sum(meth(f, a+i*h, h) for i in range(100)))
   return ival 

# Call function
func = lambda x: eval(str(a)+'*x**'+str(n))
result = round(integrate(func, c, b), 5)
```

Test programs will be posted with their running times so people can tell how fast my computer is. I will post no hardware specifications (processor type, speed) though - that will remain a mystery.

### Controller code

```python
# Gun Fight at High Noon
import subprocess, random, time, sys
from decimal import Decimal

# Get program names
prog1 = sys.argv[1]
prog1command = sys.argv[2]
prog2 = sys.argv[3]
prog2command = sys.argv[4]

# Generate numbers
a=random.randint(1, 50)
n=random.randint(1, 10)
b=random.randint(1, 50)
c=random.randint(1, 50)

# Integration using the Simpson method
def integrate(f, a, b):
   h = (b-a)/100
   meth = lambda f,x,h: (f(x) + f(x+h))/2.0
   ival = Decimal(h * sum(meth(f, a+i*h, h) for i in range(100)))
   return ival 

# Call function
func = lambda x: eval(str(a)+'*x**'+str(n))
result = round(integrate(func, c, b), 5)
function=str(a)+'*x**'+str(n)

print('A,B:     '+str(c)+','+str(b))
print('Function:    '+function)
print('Result:      '+str(result))

# Run program and evaluate output
def runprog(command, result, f, a, b):
    start = time.time()
    answer = subprocess.Popen(command+' '+str(a)+' '+str(b)+' '+f, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end-start

    if Decimal(answer) > result-Decimal(0.00005) and Decimal(answer) < result+Decimal(0.00005):
        correct = True
    else:
        correct = False

    return elapsed, correct, answer

p1time, p1correct, p1answer = runprog(prog1command, result, function, c, b)
p2time, p2correct, p2answer = runprog(prog2command, result, function, c, b)

print('\n'+prog1+': '+str(p1time)+' '+str(p1correct)+' '+p1answer)
print(prog2+': '+str(p2time)+' '+str(p2correct)+' '+p2answer)

if p1correct:
    if p2correct:
        if p1time < p2time:
            print('\nWin: '+prog1)
        elif p1time == p2time:
            print('\nTie')
        else:
            print('\nWin: '+prog2)
    else:
        print('\nWin: '+prog1)
else:
    if p2correct:
        print('\nWin: '+prog2)
    else:
        print('\nTie')
```

Comment: To be properly specified you need to define a) the class of functions which should be integrated; b) the I/O format; c) the error tolerance (and the method of computing the reference value against which you'll check). As a separate issue, what do you mean by "credentials" in the last sentence?

Comment: @PeterTaylor My answer has been edited to incorporate all of your suggestions

Comment: I don't see point a) addressed anywhere, and the part of point b) which relates to how the formula is serialised is also unaddressed. And on the basis of the example, no-one should waste their time answering. The spec allows "*a 0.005 error tolerance*" but the error in the controller's calculation is apparently 350.38575. I think the standard English term for processor type, speed, etc. would be "hardware specifications". "Credentials" in the context of computing generally means either username+password or a cryptographic token serving a similar purpose.

Comment: @PeterTaylor What do you mean by *class of functions* then?

Comment: Are answers supposed to integrate polynomials, rational polynomials, hypergeometrics, the closure under field operations of elementary functions, ...?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Elementary functions

Comment: How is this significantly different than if it was simply a [fastest-code] problem instead of having a tournament set up? You could just give a large set of test cases, and the fastest code would still win, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Rubik's Cube Simulator**

**I had posted a rubik's cube question a few days back which turned out to be quite close to an existing one although I made a few amendments. This is a different question altogether.**

The idea is to simulate operation of a rubik's cube.

**INPUT: Take a preset sticker configuration for each face as input**

Your program must interpret the configuration and suggest a list of moves to generate the said configuration from a perfect Rubik's cube.

Your program must also check if the sticker combination is an invalid one, and print an error message saying that it is not possible to generate such a configuration.

Question should probably be used as a popularity contest given the length and complexity of code, but based on response, a code golf follow-up is on the cards.

Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about Rubik's cube, but going from state Finish to In-between any different than In-between to Finish?

Comment: I don't think using [popularity-contest] is a good idea if there are better alternatives. That should be reserved for cases, when it's hard to make the validation criteria objective. In your case [code-golf] seems fine. Alternatively, you could think about a [code-challenge] for returning the smallest number of moves.

Comment: Okay, will do. Code-challenge seems more accurate.

Comment: ...awaiting response...

Answer (score 0):

**Question about symmetry in ascii grid** (temp title)

> **Synopsis:** Given a grid of ASCII characters, determine if, and in what ways, the grid is symmetrical.

Some characters are symmetrical to others. For example:

- `d` is symmetrical vertically to `b`
- `W` is symmetrical horizontally to `M`
- `O` is symmetrical both ways to `O`
- `!` is symmetrical horizontally to `i` (takes some imagination!)
- `^` is symmetrical horizontally to `v`
- `b` is rotationally symmetrical 180 degrees to `q` (that is, if you rotate the first character 180 degrees, you get the second character)
- (space) is symmetrical vertically, horizontally, and rotationally to

In this challenge, there are only three types of symmetry that need to be considered: vertical, horizontal, and rotational by 180 degrees. You can find a full list of which characters are considered symmetrical at the bottom of this post.

If we arrange some characters into an `n` by `m` rectangle (where `n` and `m` are both even integers), then the rectangle may be symmetrical. Here is an example:

```
M^^^^MM^^M
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
WvvvvWWvvW
```

It is symmetrical horizontally.

Here's another example.

```
dddbbb
dddbbb
dddbbb
ddOObb
```

It is symmetrical vertically.

Here's one more example:

```
++++++
+p++q+
++++++
++++++
+b++d+
++++++
```

This one has three ways it is symmetrical -- horizontally, vertically, *and* rotationally.

Write a program which will, when given a rectangle of characters as input, output the number of ways that rectangle is symmetrical. For the three inputs I've shown above, the outputs would be `1`, `1`, and `3` respectively.

*[Todo: list of characters]*

### Sandbox Questions

1. One thing I've been considering is allowing entrants to access the list of which characters are symmetrical (in some sort of CSV format) in a file. This would mean that entrants wouldn't have to encode the symmetries themselves. On one hand, this probably saves some frustration at having to code in all the possible symmetries. On the other, this reduces the complexity of the challenge as the aspect of encoding the symmetries with minimal characters is removed. I'd like your thoughts on this.

Comment: Yet more symmetries: all of `[]{}()` are vertically symmetric to themselves. `|` belongs in "Both". lower-case `c` belongs in vertical. Maybe also lower-case `a` depending on the font your going by (apparently not the one used on SE). Likewise `t` might belong in horizontal symmetry. We also forgot about digits: `08` both ways, `3` vertical.

Comment: What do you think about adding rotational symmetry (by 180 degrees) to the mix?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​Like `6` and `9`? I think rotational symmetry would do well as a seperate question actually.

Comment: Yes, like 6 and 9. If a new question for that is based on the same concept, it would probably be too similar to not be a duplicate (at least the solution I have in mind would be rather easily adapted to do rotational symmetry, I think). Adding it here, might open some possibilities for interesting compression/golfing.

Comment: You've convinced me. I'll edit in the rotational part when I have time.

Comment: Since there will probably be combinations of all three symmetries on different characters, I'd recommend only having one list for each symmetry (with some pairs in multiple lists). Here are the rotational pairs I can think of: d/p, b/q, (/), [/], {/}, </>, %/%, ///, \/\, ,/,, S/S, s/s, z/z, Z/Z, W/M, !/i, ^/v, $/$, as well as all those which are symmetric both ways to themselves.

Comment: Some of the characters are not visible (at least on my screen) so would benefit from being followed by a description. I think they are just spaces but markdown appears to fail to display them even in backticks.

Comment: Displaying a single space in an inline code tag has to be done with an actual `<code>` tag rather than with backticks. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/rotate-an-ascii-art-image is a good starting point for rotational symmetries. Some digits also have linear symmetries.

Comment: Would you also consider J and L as symmetrical (also requires a little imagination...)?

Answer (score 0):

## American Roulette

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Roulette is one of the simplest casino games to understand, so I invite you all to see who gets the most money.

### Coding

You will be supplied with a singe argument via the command line. This argument will be the amount of money you have.

```
[command to run your code] [arg1]
```

Your output must be in the following format:

```
[bet]|[amount of money you bet]
```

The following is a list of valid bets:

http://www.predictem.com/images/roulette.gif

```
Name                   | Example
-----------------------+-----------------------
Any number of numbers  | 12|100 or 36,19,18|100
00                     | 00|1000
0                      | 0|126
1st 12 (see image)     | 1st12|100
2nd 12 (see image)     | 2nd12|439
3rd 12 (see image)     | 3rd12|679
1 to 18                | 1-18|8
19-36                  | 19-36|10000
Red numbers            | red|1722
Black numbers          | black|1384
Odd numbers            | odd|100
Even numbers           | even|21900
```

Payout will be calculated using the following equation where `n` is the number of squares your bet will win on:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/6/9/66946b321361a701f6b6903d5eae4b44.png

In your answer, I need the name of your program, your code and a command to run it.

### Winning

When enough people enter, I will run the controller twice a week. After four weeks, I will announce the winner (the person with the most money).

#### I realise that is may be ambiguous and/or poorly worded so any feedback on how to pad this question out would be helpful.

Comment: 1. This is not a king-of-the-hill challenge, due to the lack of interaction. This is basically just a code-challenge. 2. "`n` is the number of squares" should probable be "...the number of squares your bet will win on". 3. In roulette, can you actually bet on "any number of numbers"? I thought only the groups indicated on the mat are possible. 4. You might want to specify "American Roulette" because of the `00`. 5. 5. How much money do we start with? 6. I guess you won't be just doing a single test for each bot, so how many trials will there be and how is the overall score determined?

Comment: How can the bots interact? It looks to random and too "player versus environment"-y.

Comment: Casino? The best strategy is not to play at all...

Comment: @MartinBüttner I know that *any number of numbers* violates the conventional rules, but I'll keep it just so I don't need to code the layout of a roulette table.

Comment: @Vi. Depends on the game, but in the case of Roulette you *can't* win in the long run. So I guess a reasonable winning criterion would be "most rounds until bankrupt". Still, I'm not sure Roulette provides enough strategical depth to be interesting.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, but this isn't normal roulette. If you bet `0,00,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36|all-your-money` you make a guaranteed profit of `(38/36 - 1)*all-your-money`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor lol, good point, although I don't see how that provides "enough strategical depth to be interesting" :P

Comment: @PeterTaylor You would make a guaranteed ***loss*** with that. `yourmoney -= bet; yourmoney += (38/36)-1`

Comment: @BetaDecay wait what, your payout is not multiplied by your bet? o.O

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh yeah... I should add that...

Answer (score 0):

## A game of chance

Hello!  Thought I would try out the sandbox, a rather useful tool that I haven't utilized yet!  This is a game I thought up with some colleagues, basic in theory but has some deeper algorithms to win.  I'm thinking of tagging this as code-challenge, any opinions welcome, especially a better name.

## How to Play

Every turn, you get one number, pseudo-randomly generated, you need to put this number in a list.  The list must always be in numerical order, from lowest to highest, and cannot be changed after the turn has ended.  If you can no longer put the number anywhere, where it will still be in numerical order, you lose.

The list is 100 entries, which start as empty slots (seen as "-" or unique characters for your language) and slowly becomes a list of numbers ([example that just lost](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pw6byv3n901e02/Result.png?dl=0)).

## Rules

- You cannot edit the position of a value in the list.
- The value will be inputted every turn.
- The random numbers are X-Y.  Both X and Y will always be positive and from 0 to 65535.
- I'm willing to input the number in most ways
- Any language that I can run!  I have both Windows 7 and Linux Mint + VMs for other versions.

## Scoring

You get 1 point for every round you last.  There are 10 (TBD) rounds for each score, resulting in a maximum score of 1000 (which is very unlikely to ever get).

Comment: Assuming your PRNG is uniform, how could there be a better strategy than just mapping 1 to 100 to the range the PRNG can produce and then rounding to the nearest empty cell? Or is the range of the PRNG unknown and different for each game?

Comment: Assuming the PRNG has an even chance to spit out any number in the range, the challenge can be solved optimally, so scoring by rounds lasted is not a good idea.

Comment: Assume you get the answer 99, would it be best to put it in the 99th slot or the 98th slot?  If you put it in the 99th slot, and you get 100 twice - you lose.  However if you put it in the 98th, you don't.  It's not to get all 100 slots filled, it's to get as far as possible.  It's a better game with the random numbers out of 1000, which I have just changed.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert I don't think it makes sense on average to leave that extra room for a second 100, because you might as well get more numbers below 99 than you have space there. I do believe this becomes a lot more interesting, if we're talking about an unknown PRNG range though. You'd need the first few moves to decide how much you'll spread out the numbers.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That's actually a very good idea.  Do people suggest that I do that?

Comment: @PopeyGilbert At the same time, in order not to make it too complicated, a good compromise might be to choose the endpoints of the range randomly from some small finite known set.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert I should have said "An optimal guess exists" instead of "An optimal solution exists". This is basically just building a tree and then taking the path that gives you the best odds. Making the endpoints variable just means you have to guess at that too. It might be so hard to guess that you can't make an optimal guess in a reasonable amount of time, so you may want to add a time restriction. When you add a time restriction, things get hairy and people want to know what machine they'll be running on.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm taking your suggestion, and I'll make the points random!  RainBolt, you have some very good points, I think I do understand what your saying =)  I'm already understanding how amazingly useful "The Sandbox" is.

Comment: If the deeper problems can be fixed, there are some minor changes which I think would make it easier to understand. I would talk about an *array* rather than a *list*, because I think it has stronger connotations of being a fixed size. I would clarify whether the *-* in *X-Y* is a subtraction or giving bounds of a range. And I would ask the program to give output of the array index every time it receives an input, so that your control program can validate its moves.

Comment: You refer to both numerical order and alphabetical order. Are these meant to both say numerical order, or is there an extra challenge that I have missed?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the advice!  I'll fix them tomorrow.  Also, GithubPhagocyte, they're both meant to be numerical order =)  Will correct too :D

Answer (score 0):

## Print the Constitutional Amendment

Given a number from 1 to 27, print the appropriate amendment to the US Constitution, using [this text](http://pastebin.com/kbX58C5B).

Your score is the byte count of your source code, divided by the byte count of the best answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i) in the same language. Therefore, you must use a language which had an answer to that question before September 1, 2014.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

### Question

Is this too similar to existing Kolmogorov-complexity challenges?

Comment: Hm, I think there's little regularity to the output which could be exploited, so this seems to boil down to just using any plain compression.

Answer (score 0):

### Capture the flag

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### Basic rules

There is a rectangular map of cells, each bot has current cell. Bots compete 1 vs 1 at a time, let's call them red and blue. There are N instances of red bot and N instances of the blue bot on the map. Additionally, there is unmovable red base and blue base, both having initially the red flag and blue flag respectively. Bot instances can move around, supress enemy bot instances, capture the enemy's flag. The goal is to bring enemy's flag to the base (which should have the flag). The flag can be returned back to the base. Bots can pass the flag around.

### Selectable rules (to be decided)

#### Map style

- 2D, 3D or 2.5D;
- Wrapped-around or not;
- With walls (destructible, indestructible, buildable by bots) or without;
- Bases positions and bots initial positions: random, selectable by player, hardcoded in a map?
- Random-generated, pre-programmed, partially selectable by the player?

#### Bot capabilities

- Moving diagonally? Dodging?
- Seeing the entire map or only surroundings?

#### Intra-team bot communication

- Uninhibited
- Only using messages that takes a move to create or read and that travel not too fast;
- Inhibited (only indirect by observing positions);

#### Prior knowledge

- Should bots know the walls of the map from the beginning?
- Should bots know the bases posisions from the beginning?
- Should bots know enemy bots positions from the beginning?
- If communication between bots is not free, should bots know initial frindly bots position from the beginning?

#### Attacking

- Only nearby bots or also "shooting"?
- Multiple weapons or not?
- Dodge/protect move?
- One-hit or health points?

#### Abandoned flag

- Is reset to the appropriate base after timeout;
- Is reset to the appropriate base instantly;
- Needs to be carried by the bot manually;

#### Scoring

- Reset the game after each flag score or continue the game for N moves or N scores?
- What to do in case of stalemate?

### Questions

1. Is this challenge a good idea?
2. Which set of proposed rule variants to choose?

My current choice is:

- Rectangular 2D map without wraparound, with big walls pre-programmed, random single wall-lets placed randomly;
- Bases positions are pre-defined and known in advance to all bots;
- Bots having 10 health points, carrying chainsaw (5 damage, 1 distance) and a gun (2 damage, 10 distance);
- Bots can stay&defend (half of received damage), move 1 cell to 8 directions, attack (without moving); build up to 8 pieces of wall in neighbouring cell, destroy 1 piece of neighbouring wall, capture the flag, score the goal, send a message.
- Bots can cee a 11x11 rectangle, centered around them, including through walls;
- Bots are stateful, but can't communicate with other instances directly. They can observe movements of other bots in the vision field or receive messages (if any). The message is a 4 bytes of data (i.e. a number from 0 to 2^32-1) + 1 byte of signal strength, it travels 5 cells per move, decreasing signal strength by one. Message gets received (including the current "signal strength" parameter) by all bots (including enemy ones). Bots reads the message (if any) before making a move. If there are multiple messages, only one with larger signal strength gets received. Hovewer if signal strengths differ only by 1, contect gets XORed.
- Player choses initial positions (relative to own base) of all his bots;
- All bots know the initial walls in the map;
- While the bots stays close to own base, it's health gets recovered by 1 point per move, up to 10, if the flag is present.
- Each round gets until one of the team scores 5 goals. This team wins (5-x) points, where x is number of opposin team's goals.
- Abandoned flag can be picked up by either team. All bots know relative position of the own flag at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Unbreakable Wall Maria**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) AND ( [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) OR [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) )

In order to protect the last bastion of human civilisation against giant Titans, a large wall has been constructed around the perimeter of the city. It has been decided that another large wall, within the perimeter of the first one, will be erected to ensure the protection of the city. You have been assigned to design the wall to make sure it is strong and sturdy.

A wall of height `p` and length `q` is built out of identical rectangular blocks of height `m` and length `n`. A wall is considered unsecure if there is a straight line that can divide the wall into two pieces without cutting through any of the individual blocks. To illustrate, consider a wall of height 5 and length 6, constructed of blocks of 1 height and 2 length placed in either orientation. This is the test case `5 6 1 2` (a 5x6 wall composed of 1x2 blocks). There are at least two different ways of building this wall:

[image: Image illustrating ways of presenting the walls]
*Diagram 1: Ways of building a wall*

The first wall is an *insecure* wall because there is a line that divides the wall into two pieces (into a 6x4 block and a 6x2 block). Because there is only one line that divides the wall, we can call this wall an *insecure-1* wall. An *insecure-1* wall is more secure than an *insecure-2* wall, but not as secure as a secure wall.

The second wall is a *secure* wall because there is no line that can divide the wall into two pieces without going through any of the blocks. You could also think of it as *insecure-0* if you wanted to.

A secure wall is essential to the integrity of the wall. If it is an insecure wall it will be easily breached by the Titans. Your task is to design the wall. To do this, you will write a program that takes in the height and length of the wall and the blocks as input, and output (*a graphical representation* / *an ASCII art representation*) of the most secure wall that can be created using the blocks given.

#### Input

Input consists of four space seperated integers `p`, `q`, `m`, and `n`, which represents the height of the wall, the length of the wall, the height of the blocks, and the length of the blocks.

#### Output

This is the part I'm not sure about. I've got two possibilities: either I can make the question graphical output (i.e. I would expect the program to output an actual image), or ASCII art.

Possibility 1:

Output a *graphical image* (not ASCII art) of the wall. The overall appearance of the wall (e.g. line thickness, colours used, size, etc.) is up to you, but the lines that form the individual blocks must be clearly visible, and differentiated from the rest of the wall. This means you can't pull something like "this draws a black wall with black lines", or "this draws an infinitesimally small scaled wall", etc.

Possibility 2:

Output *text based art* (not a graphical image) of the wall. It should be drawn using the [box drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). The wall must be drawn to scale, but apart from that, you have some freedom in what characters to use (so you can choose to use the double line ones if you wish), but they have to be part of the Box Drawing Unicode block. In addition, the wall must be visible, so you can't write a program that outputs nothing and say "this draws an infinitesimally small scaled wall", etc.

Question to reader: Which output format do you think would make a more interesting challenge?

Comment: As is, this seems like a math problem rather than a coding challenge. There's probably a criterion one can derive without needing to test tilings in code. But I like the idea behind the challenge. May I suggest something like generating or testing for secure walls?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@xnor I found that there was indeed a closed form solution for any case of the problem. Generating wall positions sounds like a good idea. I'll rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

### Finding repeated words in a passage

This challenge is inspired by [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11423/6834) on the Software Recommendations website.

Write a program that outputs the repeated words in a passage on a paragraph by paragraph basis.

The program should take three text files as input:

- `passage`: contains the paragraphs to be analyzed
- `blacklist`: contains a list of additional pairs that should be considered as repetitions, such as: `eat, ate; begin, began, begun`
- `whitelist`: contains a list of exceptions that should not be flagged, such as `the, a, an, to, for`

Specifications:

- In each paragraph, find the repeated words that are not in the `whitelist`. The keywords in the `whitelist` file may be separated with commas or line breaks. You are free to choose the one that best suits your needs.
- The repetitions should be allowed to differ in case, prefixes, suffixes, declension or in grammatical number. For example: `allow` and `Allowed`, `friend` and `friends`, `eat` and `eaten` should count as pairs of repetition
- Each pair specified in the `blacklist` should also be considered as a repetition. You are also free to choose how the words in the `blacklist` are separated. Ideally, these would be copied from a table of irregularites found by a simple online search
- It should support alternate spellings of German umlauts and the "double s" character in the list files. For example: `Fränze` and `Fraenze`, `Jörg` and `Joerg`, `Müller` and `Mueller`, `Gauß` and `Gauss`. The list need only contain one of these words, but both spellings should be searched
- The output should write the paragraph number, then list the repeated words and their count. For example: 

  `2: eat*3 + however*5
  4: moreover*4 + despite*2
  5: began/begun*3`

  or any representation that is just as readable

Rules:

- This is a code golf challenge; lowest byte count wins
- The input file names are excluded from the byte count

Comment: How are we supposed to deal with the grammatical variation? We can't possibly implement every single declension/conjugation of all words. Could you provide a list of words/forms which are to be treated as identical?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good idea! I should add a blacklist file

Comment: Few people write both the "umlauted" and "non-umlauted" spellings in the same piece of text. One writes, say, "Mueller" because one's environment does not support umlauts.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury True, but I am assuming that the person who writes the lists is not necessarily the same as the person writing the texts (student/teacher for example). Also, some people still prefer one spelling to another even when the environment supports it (For example, "dass" is much more common than "daß", even though they are both used)

Comment: @Timmy I agree with your first point.

Answer (score 0):

I liked [my first idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2037/25024), maybe changing the game helps.

### Sliding Code

A [sliding puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle), sliding block puzzle, or sliding tile puzzle is a puzzle that challenges a player to slide usually flat pieces along certain routes (usually on a board) to establish a certain end-configuration.

The fifteen puzzle is the oldest type of sliding block puzzle.

[image]

**The challenge**

Write a code that behaves as a sliding board. Given a configuration it should run when such configuration is solvable and not run (aka have compile/runtime errors) if the configuration is not solvable.

**Rules**

- The board is your code. It is a 4x4 grid with a total of 15 square tiles with side length >= 1.
- Each tile, taken alone, should output it's number in the board (from `k + 1` to `k + 15` with `int k` of your choice).

**Output**

Each tile should output its static value (not the actual value). The tile that outputs `13` will output `13` in every different configuration.

The whole board should output `true` (or 1 or whatever while it express a truthy value) if the configuration can reach the final state: ascending tile numbers on the board from left to right, up to down and the `k` void tile in the bottom right position.

**Score**

This is tile [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the minimum tile side length wins, meaning a minimum score of 1 can be achieved. If a tie, the greatest `k` value serves as tie-breaker.

Comment: The tiles should be squares. `side*side = side^2` thus the score only depends by the side. I'll remove code-challenge tag.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense then.

Answer (score 0):

### Facing a martian fractal

[Fractals are awesome](http://www.pinterest.com/ohgrammyio/fractals-are-awesome/).

They can be used for a very large number of pratical purposes, from [antennas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_antenna) to [self-similarity of complex networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension_on_networks).

One of the most fantastic uses of fractals tough remains [3D terrain landscaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_landscape).

[image: weee! awesome]

With such technique you can create awesome landscapes:

[image: This is actually computer generated]

---

[Mars is awesome](http://www.viralnova.com/mars-is-awesome/).

The red planet is surrounded in a veil of mistery for its early earth-like life.

Also, as you know, is full of [martians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydonia_(region_of_Mars)):

[image]

In this photo we are [facing a martian face on mars](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia).

---

**The Challenge**

Your task is to create a fractal landscape which resembles the martian face.

- The prospective can be the most convinient for you as long as the face and the landscape are recognizable.
- The output should be a few frames GIF of landcape creation, to ensure that fractal approach has been used (just like the one above).
- You don't need to use the martian face, another landscape can be used as model as long as it has a pareidolic effect of a face in it. You can also not use a model and "draw" the face yourself.
- Colors are optional. Obviously they will give a greater chance to get more votes.

Here are some other models if you are a bit short of ideas:
[image]
[image]
[image]

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: While this sounds quite fun, I'm not entirely sure where the programming challenge is in that. In the end it just comes down to who finds the best parameters for the fractal they use. Moreover, it should be possible to automate this by restricting oneself to using octaves of sines and figuring out which ones to use by Fourier transforming the desired output.

Comment: At the moment this is too broad and set up as an art contest. You need to define what qualifies as a "*fractal approach*": saying that you'll eyeball a gif is neither objective nor accurate, because I could just hard-code a mesh, run some simplification, and output the frames in reverse order. And allowing the use of any target model whatsoever means it will be judged on those models. This could be reworked into a programming contest if the program has to search a parameter space to find parameters which make a specific fractal generation technique generate the best approximation to Cydonia.

Comment: Although that does still leave an issue of hard-coding, as Martin alludes to.

Comment: I think this slips into the [implementation vs output in popularity contests diatribe](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2196/25024). In the challenge there is no input, I can't understand how _restricting oneself to using octaves of sines and figuring out which ones to use by Fourier transforming the desired output_ is considered hard coding. Isn't it the point of the challenge? Moreover a _fractal approach_ is self explanatory: [generate random fractal terrain](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#ptI), explaining why is fractal and which algorithm was used is answerer's task.

Comment: I should add that standard loopholes doesn't apply, but at this point I tought it to be paid.

Comment: It is most certainly not self-explanatory that "*a fractal approach*" means that randomness is involved. Most of the best known fractals have no randomness whatsoever. The defining attribute of a fractal is debated, so if the spec requires a fractal you should give a working definition, and if you use a common one such as a non-integral Hausdorff dimension then ideally you should provide a link to some kind of tool for estimating it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose my last suggestion was way too complex, so here's something else.

## Blade Competition (Simple Card Game)

[image]

Certain RPG's include mini games that are quite a bit simpler than board and card games such as chess and poker, not too hard to implement and understand, but still complex enough to be interesting. So let's play Blade.

## Rules

[Images are better than words, so here's a short video of me playing Blade. I'm not trying to win, I'm trying to show off some interesting cases. Should be self-explanatory, the goal is to get as many points as possible.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1a10OdYp_g#t=195)

32 cards (see below). 2 players get a deck of 16 cards each (randomly). They both draw 10 cards initially and take turns discarding cards to their field. The goal is to maximize the sum of the card's values on your side of the field.

Before they start taking turns, both players draw a card from their deck and place it on their field. The player with the lower score begins. If their scores are equal, both player a new card from their decks.

When a player discard a card to his field, he loses if his new score is still lower than his opponent's score. When the player's score is higher, the game moves on to the opponents turn. When both player's scores are equal, all cards on the field are discarded, and they draw a new card from their decks as described above.

There are 9 different card. Numbered cards from 1 to 7, whose value is 1-7. And two special cards, called `Bolt` and `Mirror`, whose value is 1 when they are used as the initial card.

When a player plays `Mirror`, both player's fields are exchanged with each 
other.

When a player plays `Bolt`, the last card played by the opponent gets invalidated and does not count towards the score anymore. It gets removed permanently once the opponent plays a numbered card 1-7.

A player may play a "1" and discard it to re-validate his invalidated card.

[See the github for a detailed explanation of the rules.](https://github.com/blutorange/Blade-SenNoKiseki-/blob/master/README.md) This is only for reference, the rules as implemented by the controller program are final. If you think there's a bug, leave a comment.

## Input

- stdin
- One line, including a newline, with a json object representing the current state of the game.
- json["file"] is the absolute path of a file you may use for storing information, it gets cleared once when the controller program is started.
- Your program (cli) gets called once for each decision it needs to make.
- That is, choosing a card to play, or choosing an initial card when there are no cards left in your deck.

## Response

- stdout
- A number, including a newline, representing the card you wish to play.
- 0 corresponds to the first card in the json["player"]["hand"] array.

## Scoring

- both players start with a score of 0
- N (to be decided) turns, timelimit T (tbd), for each turn:

  - Draw: score +1
  - Win: score +2
  - Lose: score +0
- Each program plays against each other program, the program with the highest score wins. I may add a few players of my own, but they won't be ranked.

## Controller Program

[Github](https://github.com/blutorange/Blade-SenNoKiseki-)

```
ruby controller.rb <playerfile> <timelimit> <rounds> <quiet>
```

See `players.txt` for the syntax of the `playerfile`. Set quiet to `y` to suppress debug output. Set it to `n` to to get a lot of information about the match, use this for debugging or if the rules are unclear. See below for a sample match with quiet set to `n`.

Please provide a cli line I can use to run your program on linux. I might be able to get Windows on a virtual machine.

## Deck

```
Card_Designation Number_of_Cards (Card's Value)

1 2 (1)
2 3 (2)
3 4 (3)
4 4 (4)
5 4 (5)
6 3 (6)
7 2 (7)
B 6 (1)
M 4 (1)
```

(B=Bolt, M=Mirror)

## Sample JSON input

- [link, sample below](https://github.com/blutorange/Blade-SenNoKiseki-/blob/master/sample_json)
- newlines and spaces added for legibility
- `file` is the absolute path of a file you may use for storing information, it gets cleared once when the controller program is started
- `lastmove` is the last card played by the player / opponent, or null if no move has been made yet
- card `type`s 1-7 correspond to the cards `1` to `7`, card type `0` is `Bolt`, `8` is `Mirror`

Everything else should be self-explanatory.

```
{
  "file": "/home/.../cg_blade/files/basic",
  "turn": 15,
  "player": {
    "hand": [
      {
        "type": 8,
        "value": 1,
        "valid": true
      },
      ......
    ],
    "field": [
      {
        "type": 8,
        "value": 1,
        "valid": true
      },
      ......
      {
        "type": 7,
        "value": 7,
        "valid": true
      }
    ],
    "deck": 5,
    "score": 30,
    "lastmove": {
      "type": 6,
      "value": 6,
      "valid": true
    }
  },
  "opponent": {
    "hand": 2,
    "field": [
      {
        "type": 3,
        "value": 3,
        "valid": true
      },
      ......
      {
        "type": 6,
        "value": 6,
        "valid": true
      }
    ],
    "deck": 5,
    "score": 32,
    "lastmove": {
      "type": 8,
      "value": 1,
      "valid": true
    }
  }
}
```

## Sample match

[Link, sample below.](https://github.com/blutorange/Blade-SenNoKiseki-/blob/master/sample_match)

A sample match generated with the controller program and quiet set to `n`. A bit long, but shows a few interesting cases.

```
Match between both players starts.
<basic> vs. <basic>


Initializing round 0.
Each player gets a deck of 16 cards.
Player 0: 3 6 5 3 6 7 B 5 2 4 B B 5 1 B B
Player 1: 1 2 4 4 3 3 M B M 5 2 6 7 4 2 M
Each player draws 10 cards.
Player 0: 1 2 4 5 5 B B B B B
Player 1: 2 2 4 5 6 7 B M M M
Cards remaining in each deck:
Player 0: 3 6 5 3 6 7
Player 1: 1 2 4 4 3 3


Round 0 starts.


Field initialization starts.
Player 0 draws initial card.
Player draws 7, and puts it on the field.
Player 1 draws initial card.
Player draws 3, and puts it on the field.
Player 1 gets first turn.


# Number in parentheses is the total score of the cards on the field.
Turn 0 starts.
Player 1's turn.
Player 0's field: 7 (7)
Player 1's field: 3 (3)
Player 0's hand (10): 1 2 4 5 5 B B B B B
Player 1's hand (10): 2 2 4 5 6 7 B M M M
Cards remaining in player 0's deck: 5.
Cards remaining in player 1's deck: 5.
Player 1 plays 5.
Player 1 ends his turn.
Player 0's field: 7 (7)
Player 1's field: 3 5 (8)


Turn 1 starts.
Player 0's turn.
Player 0's field: 7 (7)
Player 1's field: 3 5 (8)
Player 0's hand (10): 1 2 4 5 5 B B B B B
Player 1's hand (9): 2 2 4 6 7 B M M M
Cards remaining in player 0's deck: 5.
Cards remaining in player 1's deck: 5.
Player 0 plays 2.
Player 0 ends his turn.
Player 0's field: 7 2 (9)
Player 1's field: 3 5 (8)
......
......
```

Comment: I haven't thought hard about loopholes, but one quick observation: I don't think you specify anywhere how many copies of each card are in the deck.

Comment: [See the detailed rules on github.](https://github.com/blutorange/Blade-SenNoKiseki-/blob/master/README.md) But you're right, perhaps I should add a note.

Answer (score 0):

**Position the Border Guard**

*[Currently INCOMPLETE. Posting here to save.]*

You are in charge of defending an island from an invasion force. To do this, you decide to place *n* guard posts around the perimeter of your island. You decide that the most effective way to ensure that the whole island is equally guarded is to equally distribute your guard posts around the perimeter of the island. In other words, if someone went around the perimeter your island with a surveyor's wheel, measuring the distance between guard posts walking on the perimeter, it would be equal for every guard post. For instance, if the island were a perfect circle, and I had to place 2 guard posts, they would be placed opposite to each other.

Of course, the island is not a perfect circle. We can describe the shape of the island as sequence of arcs joined together as one cohesive shape, like the clouds in [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2168/21682). The one difference is that in this question, there will never be a hole in the island. Given an input in the form

```
n island
```

Where `n` is the number of guard posts to place and `island` is a space separated list of comma separated tuples `x,y,r` indicating the x position, y position, and radius of the circles that construct the island, output `n` 2-tuples indicating the x and y positions to place the guard posts in.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a Ray Tracer

[A ray tracer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)) is a program which, for each pixel in an virtual screen, traces a path from an imaginary eye through that pixel and calculates the color of the object visible through it.

[image]

Ray tracers are famously small enough to fit on a business card!  [Code and explanation here](http://fabiensanglard.net/rayTracing_back_of_business_card/index.php).

Tired of seeing ray tracers that just render a spheres or a sphere and a box and, if you're lucky, a torus?  This challenge addresses this.

This task is to [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) a ray tracer that renders a [true color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_color) scene specified by arguments.  The arguments are:

1. A triangle mesh, specified by the filename of an [.obj mesh file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)
2. The [diffuse, ambient and specular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjA_sC4bCAM) ([more](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html)) colors for the entire mesh
3. A camera, specified by position, direction, up and field-of-view in degrees
4. A [point](http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=11) light source, specified by position and color
5. A directional light source, specified by direction and color

The output shall be a [.ppm file](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), which can be converted to jpg for inclusion in the answer.

There are lots of .obj files available on the Internet e.g. [a teapot, cow and teddy bear](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F03/models/) and these [standard test meshes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_3D_test_models).

Comment: Very much related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17270/raytracer-in-odd-or-high-level-language ... Also you might want to include a bit more about ambient, diffuse and specular materials, or ray tracing in general. The current spec basically assumes that everyone knows how a ray tracer works.

Comment: Requiring loading an obj and mtl file is a stretch for a codegolf.

Comment: @Sparr I strip the mtl but the obj is just a few lines, at least in Python.  This is codegolf but C and Java etc are going to stand a chance and, by making the input external, entrants cannot try and golf the scene itself.

Comment: I don't know what the "*normal*" of a camera is, but to properly specify a camera takes three vectors, typically *position*, *look*, and *up*. (And some clipping planes, and a width of field).

Comment: @Will if you're allowing a python library that loads obj files to be used, that's even worse. that puts any language without an obj library at a debilitating disadvantage

Comment: @Sparr no, I meant loading obj in pure python is not many lines.  I picked it as the simplest mesh format out there.  The key thing is, if people embed the scene in the code then this becomes an **art contest**, which is hated with a passion on this site.

Comment: @Will You could provide a heightmap as textual input. That would be a suitably simple input case for a code golf, imho

Comment: @Sparr to convince myself that parsing an obj file is super trivial, here's the pure Python, not even golfed: https://gist.github.com/williame/5799b75baf6bff3137ba ; obj is just a list of vertices and a list of faces.

Answer (score 0):

## Sudden Death Rummy

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) with following rules: A 50 game match is played and the winner gets an average score per game. This average score is then multiplied by the bytecount of the program. The winner is the program with the lowest product of average score and bytecount.

Rummy is a card game where the objective is to get rid of all cards in your hand by forming "melds". A meld is either a consecutive series of cards in the same suit, or 3/4 cards of different suits of the same value, which is, in ascending order A(ce), 2-10, V(alet), Q(ueen) or K(ing). A meld is always at least 3 cards, and 13 cards at the most.

In my regional variant of discard rule Rummy, there are 7 rounds. the first 6 rounds require you to put down N+2 cards in 1 or more melds, then discard 1 card, then finish your turn, before you can start using existing melds or put down new melds. in the 7th round, you NEED to be able to place down your entire hand and discard the one card in 1 turn, before your opponent can do this. You start with 10 cards, and every turn you cannot empty your entire hand, you draw another card and give the turn to the opponent. The actual system involves buying cards and bidding wars, but to simplify, it's just round robbing cards until one of them finishes.

---

Your task: Create a Rummy bot that plays against itself.

Input: a number between 1 and 100 denoting how many games should be played.

your program needs to generate 2 random legitimate hands as the first task. The deck starts with 104 cards: 2 full decks, 4 suits per deck, 13 cards per suit. 10 cards per hand from the deck.

second task: one hand randomly starts. If the program cannot make a legitimate Sudden Death Rummy hand clear, it draws a random card and hands the turn to the other hand. If the program CAN make a legitimate hand clear, it displays 2 lines. The first line is a comma-separated list displaying the winning hand clear. The second line is the sum of the value of the cards of the other hand, with number cards being their respective value and A/V/Q/K being 10 points each. this task switches between players until one of them is the winner. If the game lasts long enough for the deck to be depleted, no victor is declared and both hands get scored according to the above rules.

3rd task: after a victor is chosen, the next game starts. task 1 and 2 are repeated until there have been as many games as the input indicates. At this point, the match ends. The victor is the side who has the lowest amount of points after the end of the last game.

[**Sandbox Note:** I need to: Figure out a scoring method that doesn't require multiplying or averaging average score and bytecount without encouraging high bytecounts or average scores; decide whether to include a runtime limit; Decide whether the program should also display the hand and drawn cards.]

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate an arbitrary linear recursive sequence

in this question given a recursive definition for a sequence we need to output a formula for the given sequence.

in this question, a linear recursive sequence is a sequence of the form:

```
a_0 = c_0
a_1 = c_1
...
a_{m-1} = c_{m-1}

for n >= m: a_n = x_1*a_{n-1} + x_2*a_{n-2} + ... + x_m*a_{n-m}
```

where `m, c_1 ... c_{m-1}, x_1 ... x_m` are all constants.

for example, such a definition (the fibonacci numbers):

```
a_0 = 0 // c_0 is 0
a_1 = 1 // c_1 is 1
for n >= 2: a_n = 1*a_{n-1} + 1*a_{n-2} // x_1 is 1 and x_2 is 1
```

the answer may be a function and get input as two lists, one containing `a_0...a_{m-1}` and one containing `x_1 ... x_m`, and return a string, or be a complete program and get the input as a space separated numbers.

because polynomials of degree up to 5 can be solved but polynomials of degree 5 or higher can't, the solution may assume that `m` is smaller than 5.

the output must be a formula that given `n` returns `a_n`. if two formulas are different but both return the same output for every index, both of them can be outputted. so, for the powers of 2, both `(1+1)^n` and `2*2^n - 2^n` can be outputted.
in the output `√5` denotes the square root of 5, as does `2√5`. `3√5` denotes the third root of 5.

#### Example input and output:

```
f ([0,1],[1,1]) (fibonacci numbers) can result in ((1+√5)^n-(1-√5)^n)/√5
f ([1],[2])     (the powers of 2)   can result in 2^n
f ([1,2],[1,2]) (the powers of 2 again)
```

**bonus:**
if your solution uses no library function which solves equations, -80 bytes.

this is code golf, so smallest byte count wins

Comment: This seems to hinge largely on solving the polynomial equation for the characteristic roots. For the Fibonacci one, would outputting floats in place of `1+√5` and `1-√5` be valid?

Comment: @xnor what should I do? I guess allowing floats leads to an easier question, but outputting the exact formula is more mathematical.

Comment: @xnor I think floats won't be allowed

Comment: How then would one represent the roots of a fifth-degree polynomial? They're not generically algebraic. Maybe you can restrict to two-term recurrences to get quadratics. It would certainly make solving them and fitting to initial conditions easier, though perhaps that's less interesting.

Comment: Could you please add some `{}` to your first code block and be consistent with the use of `_` to indicate subscripts? At present, it seems to be more work than it should be to figure out how to read the equations.

Comment: While it's true that cubics and quartics can be solved in radicals, the solutions are pretty ugly. I strongly advise you to write a reference solution so that you understand what you're asking for before you post the question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was searching for the formulas and found this http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/ . it is possible, but i guess the best solutions would just copy-paste the variables into the formulas, which isn't very interesting

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe restricting to qubic equations and requiring floats instead of √ would be more interesting because the solution will have to actually compute the solutions

Comment: @proudhaskeller I think that allowing floats is cleaner, but there's subtleties there too. Solution might use iterative rather than exact methods to find roots, so you'd need to specify a tolerance and bounds on the coefficients of your recursion. Also, the formula is different when you have a double-root, which solutions might fail to detect due to float precision issues.

Comment: @xnor how is the formula different? I didn't get that

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129849/linear-homogeneous-recurrence-relations-with-repeated-roots-motivation-behind-l

Comment: @xnor I totally forgot that

Comment: @xnor Maybe the input should be restricted to not include these cases

Answer (score 0):

## Fake the forecast #2

Somewhat unfairly, your boss wasn't happy with your [last attempt at forecast fakery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/fake-the-forecast).

She's giving you one last chance, with extra stipulations.

**This time your task is to draw a map, as a grid of arrows, representing both wind speed and direction**.

- A grid is 8 tiles by 8 tiles.
- A tile is an [arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29) representing a direction and a speed.
- There are 8 potential wind directions, represented by the direction of the arrow:

  1. [image: N] N
  2. [image: NE] NE
  3. [image: E] E
  4. [image: SE] SE
  5. [image: S] S
  6. [image: SW] SW
  7. [image: W] W
  8. [image: NW] NW
- There are 6 potential wind speeds, represented by the colour of the arrow (e.g. [image: speeds]):

  1. ## 00F (<20 mph)
  2. ## 0FF (21-30 mph)
  3. ## 0F0 (31-40 mph)
  4. ## FF0 (41-50 mph)
  5. ## F00 (51-60 mph)
  6. ## F0F (>60 mph)

**There are geographical restrictions:**

- Each tile has a terrain type, land (L) or sea (S). These are:

  ```
  S L L L L L S S
  S S S L L L L S
  S S S L L L L S
  S S S S L L L L
  S S L S S L L S
  S S S S L S L L
  S S S L L S S S
  S S S S S S S S
  ```
- Wind speed on land may only be between 1 and 4
- Wind speed at sea may only be between 3 and 6

**Variation must be gradual**, specifically:

- If a feature (i.e. direction or speed) differs from one of its 4 adjoining tiles (or 3 for side tiles, 2 for corner tiles) it can only differ by one increment or decrement from that neighbour. e.g. a tile whose neighbour has wind speed 4 may have a wind speed of 3, 4 or 5 (assuming it accords with other neighbours).
- Directions can loop around, i.e. N -> NW and NW -> N. However, speeds cannot.

Because your boss is looking for believable maps, she has introduced **four arbitrary restrictions**:

- There is always at least 1 tile with wind speed 6
- There is always at least 1 tile with wind speed 1
- A wind speed of 6 is always northeasterly
- A wind speed of 1 is always southwesterly

**Maps must be unique**, don't generate the same map for different inputs.

- Input is a positive non-zero integer corresponding to the days between now and your forecast (e.g. 1 is tomorrow's forecast, 365 is a year's time).
- Output can be any format (e.g. image or text) but must take the form of a grid of arrows
- Output should be reproducible — the same input will always give the same output
- Each output must be unique from those generated using a lower input.

Because you really need to impress your boss this time, you should aim to give valid output for as many days in to the future as you can. Therefore, **scoring is based on input limit:**

- Your submission's input limit is regarded as 1 less than the lowest input that gives non-unique or otherwise invalid output.
- For instance, if valid and unique output is produced for an input of 1, 2 or 3 but not 4, your input limit is 3.

**The winner is the submission with the highest input limit** - i.e. the submission which continues to give valid and unique output up to the largest input.

There is a 768 byte limit on source code. **If there is a draw the entry with the fewest bytes wins**, so keep it short.

---

Here's an **example of valid output** (terrain shown for illustrative purposes only):

[image: example]

*Some clarifications:*

- *There needn't be a relation between forecasts, consecutive or otherwise (except that they must be unique).*
- *Outside of a submission's 'input limit' there is no defined output.*
- *There are no graphical restrictions except those specified.*
- *You may supply the terrain definition grid as input - in which case it wont count towards your byte count*
- *No other input or fetching of external data is permitted*
- *The link to the previous question is purely in theme, no rules are carried across and previous solutions (clearly) wouldn't be valid here.*
- *You don't have to draw the terrain type or any other embelishments - you can if you want but it isn't a popularity contest*

### Sandbox Questions

- Would this question be marked as a [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/fake-the-forecast)?
- Is a 768 byte limit too restrictive? Too easy?
- Have I left any loopholes?

Comment: 1. I think you need to come up with something more radical than your last question to stop it from being closed as a dup. 2. Why 768? It seems very specific..

Answer (score 0):

### Translator to Minimize the Number of Characters

With code golf you are attempting to minimize the number of characters or bytes.  The languages are, however, all just ASCII characters.  While I do not want to see this in other code golf challenges, can you use more exotic characters to do the job?

CJam, for example, only uses ASCII characters in its code but many other characters can be placed into the compiler as a strings. I wrote a simple translator to test this out which can be coverted to:

`㉕ァײோ¸༘ݩײ౲ᖒⲫ㶚ቲ㑼ᇦ㰌⧑༘ઃ௉ⲫ௔ྭഞࠗ㒍⾺`

While this is intentionally not an acceptable answer for various reasons, it shows the range of possible characters the interpreter can identify. Please note unusual things that happend as you attempt to highlight the text.

### The Challenge

1. Choose an online interpreter such as [Ideone](http://ideone.com/), [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/), or [Golfscript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/) and a language which can be run on that interpreter.  This is so I know I am using pretty much the same resources as you are when I run your answer.
2. Create a translator in your stated language which accepts an "original" input code from the same language. It then outputs a string which can be pasted in your answer or in a comment on this site.
3. Create a second translator into which the previous output string can easily be incorporated.  When this combined string and translator are run, it will run the original input code.

Please note:

- The original input code to score your answer will be the same for any
  answers of the same language.
- This code for scoring will be subject to change and the translator must work for any code of that language the interpreter accepts. (exceptions listed below).
- This code for scoring will only contain ASCII characters and I will attempt to take it from existing answers on this site.  At request it can exclude line breaks or specific characters for an additional 5% to your score AT MY DISCRESION (for instance Java code needs to be able to have spaces in it, I can't avoid that).
- The input code for scoring will be roughly 500 characters long. However, you transltors need to work regardless of the length of the input code so you can't take advantage of the fact that the code is even/odd.  It does not need to work for null input.
- Any errors or anything malicious will obviously be disqualified.
- The compressed code must be copy/pastable to codegolf SE.
- When running the code from its translated form, the code must be able to accept input.  This input is not going to be part of the code to be translated.
- Any null case which does not compact the original code in any way is disqualified.

### Scoring

- Minimum score wins (surprise surprise)
- **Score is the number of characters you need to run the original code minus the number of characters in the original input code plus 500 (combined with any modifiers).**
- The length of the original translator does not matter.
- 5% is added to your score for each character/symbol your language often makes use of but your translators cannot handle.  I can disqualify for this if I believe that the missing character too severly cripples the programmer.
- 5% is removed from your score if your two translators are the same piece of code (aka the translation is reversible).
- 5% is removed from your score if all characters in the compressed output are visible (no invisible ASCII characters). White space (spaces, tabs, line breaks) are visible but ASCII character 19 (for instance) is not.
- 3% is removed from your score if all characters are visually distinguishible (no two characters look the same but are read differently by the interpreter). The more obvious this is the better.
- 10% if anyone provides an acceptable example input code where the score without modifiers would be longer than the original input code.  This would mean the translator effectively did not compress the input code.

Comment: What's the use of the +500? Everyone's getting it, so the differences don't change at all.

Comment: What happens if you remove/add 5% to a negative or zero score?

Comment: A negative number becomes smaller and zero . . . remains zero. OK, I see your point now.

Comment: 1. A map that is equal to its inverse is called involutive, not reversible. 2. The "input code" should be the same for all submissions. It won't be fair otherwise. 3. The first, third and fifth bonus seem rather subjective. 4. I don't understand the penultimate bullet point. 5. Am I right to assume that *number of characters you need to run the original code* is the number of characters of the encoded string plus the decoder?

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THE INPUT. I will try and adress concerns. 1. Ill include involutive if I post is but the map doesnt need to be involutive if the encoder can tell if the input is encoded. That was my intention. 2) the code would need to be in the same language as the language it is programmed in. Wont work for submissions in different languages to have the same input code. 3) ill try to find a way to clarify them. Only the first has a subjective component and would be available to anyone who asks for the point fee. I dont mean look simular, I mean print exactly identical symbols.

Comment: 4) I will try and rewrite it. I meant there is a penalty if the encoder does not shorten some valid code of the appropriate length. 5) yes... These are my initial reactions. I am more than willing to remove bonuses if they complicate things too much. I think i need to include examples. I mean them there to make it easier to promote more answers. I dont want invisible characters but I would rather have answers with them than no answer. Again, thank you for the input. I like the idea and want to see it flushed out better than I probably could.  Is there a good way to fix #2?

Answer (score 0):

## Build a Version Control System [WIP] [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Git, SVN, Mercurial and Bazaar are just too bloated for you. You want something simple. Something as short as possible.

## Rules

- Your program will be invoked every time an operation needs to be made to the repository.
- Your program must take commands from command-line arguments.
- The implementation of how the program stores its own data does not matter. Input and output format do.
- Give your version control program a name and version numbering (so I can keep track of when you update it).

## Repositories

A "repository" is a directory with files and directories in it, as well as (a) special file(s) that store settings and information for the repository. These special files may not be included in version control. All other files in that directory should be included in version control.

## Features

- 'init' command - sets up a repository in the working directory

  - [BONUS 20pts] If a repository already exists in the working directory, erase or reset it first
- 'destroy' command - removes all of your special version control files from the repository. If you are not in the root directory of a repository, keep moving up one level until you find VCS files. If you reach the top level of the filesystem without finding your VCS files, don't do anything.

  - [BONUS 15pts] Exit with status 1 if no VCS files are found

## Scoring

Your score is the length of your code in bytes, minus all bonuses. Lowest score wins.

Comment: What should "*every time you change the program*" say? I'm not sure whether it should be s/change/run/ or s/program/repository/.

Comment: Do you need to generate diffs and resolve conflicts? That's a whole challenge on its own.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean that your entry into the competition needs to have version numbering - so I can see that you've edited your post and added features. Probably not too important

Comment: @xnor Currently what I have in mind is a mechanism for committing changes, viewing a log of changes (diffs) and reverting to a particular commit - probably not much more (or if there is more, make it a bonus). By 'resolve conflicts' you mean when users A and B clone the same version, then both submit commits?

Comment: Yes, usually in version control systems, when two users make parallel changes to the same file, it tries to merge the changes. If they are consistent or to different parts of the file, the changes are merged. If not, a "conflict" is presented with options on how to resolve the inconsistency. See diff3 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge. This is a tricky algorithmic problem on its own, so perhaps it should be outside of the scope of your challenge.

Comment: @xnor You're right. I think I'll restrict this to a single-user system (i.e. no clone/pull/push). Should those features be available as bonuses though? Or a separate challenge? Maybe the bonus should just be "Implement a system for resolving conflicts, using an external, existing tool for conflict resolution"

Comment: @professorfish Sounds reasonable, though perhaps you should say exactly what features it needs and what types of tools are OK, lest golfers cut too many corners. For diffs, will changes the to system be provided like "XYZ" inserted after line 1? Or will it be just be given the new file and have to produce the diff from the old file? If the second, then algorithmic alignment is also a challenge. It needs a notion of quality to prevent cheap diffs that claim the user deleted the whole file and added a new one when actually a single line was changed.

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate the Delacorte Number of a square - [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41362/calculate-the-delacorte-number-of-a-square)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Comment: Please help me improve this and add it to the directory (I can't). How to get syntax highlighting here? Please vote if you think it is a good idea and should be posted.

Comment: I think you should include all relevant definitions in sufficient detail so that the challenge is self-contained and people don't *need* to follow the links to understand the challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was also thinking about it. My current short explanation is a little golfed itself :) - but I have an explanation, I have an example and the expected result (just added, please refresh). What is your suggestion I should add from the linked page? I think it is not necessary to have the same detail.

Comment: It's more readable to put the short explanation first and then the link to a more detailed explanation. I don't think that a more detailed explanation is necessary, though, as long as you clear up the ambiguity about which metric you're using for "*distance²*". It would be good to have a test case which is a bit less structured. It would be very good to have a brief statement of motivation (which would seem to be that there's a contest to maximise and minimise Delacorte numbers for a given side length).

Comment: Finally, if the space dedicated to explaining your scoring system is 4 or 5 times as much as the space dedicated to explaining the problem, you've probably over-complicated it. What's wrong with asking for a function which takes the square as an array or string, optionally with a second argument giving the side length?

Comment: Ok, I improved it, what do you think now? Regarding the over-complicated rules: I am pretty new here, and from the code-golf-challenges I have seen, I got the feeling that this detail is necessary. I would prefer the same fixed rules (or a set I can choose from) for all challenges, so it would not be necessary to post them here. Asking for a function sounds wrong because some languages have a different concept. With my code examples I just wanted to give a feeling about the intentions, but I cannot do that for all languages... Side length should not be given as input, only the square.

Comment: Thanks for adding this to the directory. I will post this soon if I don't get any more comments. Is the Title ok? Any hints? It's my first one.

Comment: If you want a specific person to see a comment, you should use an @ tag: e.g. @maf-soft. The reason you were notified about Martin's and my comments was that they're in reply to your answer: I've only just seen that you replied to me because I came looking for the question to ask how you're getting on in the actual contest. I still think it would benefit from saying that you're measuring *Euclidean* distance (as opposed to e.g. Manhattan distance).

Comment: As for the scoring: [tag:code-golf] implies *a* set of rules, and there are some currently active discussions in meta.codegolf about default assumptions on program vs function and forms of I/O.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thanks. Is that you in the highscore list? :) I currently don't have the time to work on it, but i will. It's fun! Of course you are right, that it's not immediately clear what distance is meant. But I think, due to the examples, it is clear enough. I think it's ok and intended, when contestants have to think a bit :)

Comment: Yes, that's me. I'm quite pleased with how well I've managed to do already with fairly basic techniques.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, yes, reaching a score of 24.5 of the maximum 25 doesn't require very clever-clever effort :) but you will see, getting under the top ten is really hard and you need a lot of free time, I don't have. Two months left!

Comment: It's posted now (did I do it right?), can anyone remove it from the dictionary?

Comment: @maf-soft I removed it from the directory.  The next step is deleting this sandbox answer to clear up space.

Answer (score 0):

## One digits or two digits

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Here’s the rule:

They're 2 players. Each player has a pool of $99.

The player that takes the first turn will choose to invest an amount of $$$ taken (deducted)from your own pool. Then other player will do the same.

Who invests more wins the round. Who wins the most round is the match winner.

Unless it’s not that simple.

They’re a few twist:

**Your opponent know how many points you use, well almost.**

After you invest, your opponent know if you invest one digit number or two digit number. They’re told instantly after you invest your points. Just one or two digits. Not precisely.

**WARNING:** Player who moves first still get notified about your opponent who moves second.

**Your opponent know how many points you still have left in your pool, well almost.**

They’re only told if you have either $0 to $19, $20 to $39, $40 to $59 points, $60 to $79 points or $80 to $99. They’re told instantly after you invest your money.

WARNING: Since the notification is instant, that means if I move second, I got to know your score level before I move. If I notice a level change when you move first, I will know the level change before I make my move second. So I can act according to it.

**It’s best of 9, and those $99 must survive those 9 rounds.**

So you don't want to invest all $99 in round 1. Well, it doesn’t mean that you have to spread those $99 exactly in 9 rounds. You can use those $99 in any mean to get victory. If you have a sure-fire strategy that will give you a guaranteed win, but it needs you to use all your $99 in the first 5 round, by all mean, go. Just remember that invested point don’t return back to your point pool, win or lose.

**In first round, the player who moves first decided randomly. In following round, the player who wins previous round moves first. If tie, the player who moves first last round, moves first again**

---

**SCORING METHOD**

Each bot will be run double robin. The winner of the match results 1 point. Tie 1/2 point. Lose 0 point. After the match up, bot with most points declared as champion

---

**COMMUNICATION PROTOCOL**

During your turn, I will run your program and gives you lines of query from STDIO

Each line is a query of this following type:

`START`

Every input start with this.

`YOU xx`

This means that in that round, you played xx(exact number of dollar you invested)

`ENEMY x y`

This means enemy invest x digit int that round (x is 1 if enemy invested 1 digit, x is 2 if enemy invested 2 digit) and y is the money level after the player invests(y is 0 for $0 to $19, 2 for $20 to $39, 3 for $40 to $59, 4 for $60 to $79, 5 for $80 to $99)

`FINISH`

End of query. We expect you to give us output.

Your output must be to stdout and a single positive integer (0 is allowed)

---

**EXAMPLE:**

The match is between DEO vs WORLD. It was decided that DEO moves first.

ROUND 1

Deo will receive this query:

```
START
FINISH
```

Deo decides to invest $10. Now he only has $89.

WORLD receive this query:

```
START
ENEMY 2 5
FINISH
```

What WORLD deduces is that DEO played from $10 ~ $19. WORLD knew that DEO played at least $10 because the query said that `ENEMY 2..` and WORLD knew that DEO played at most $19, because if DEO played $20, the query will be `ENEMY 2 4`

WORLD decides to invest $20.

In round one, DEO invests $19 while WORLD invests $20. Since WORLD invests more, WORLD receive 1 point.

Enter to round 2: WORLD starts first, since winner starts first by the rule

WORLD receive this query:

```
START
ENEMY 2 5
YOU 20
FINISH
```

WORLD decides to invest $0.

DEO receive this query:

```
START
YOU 19
ENEMY 2 4
ENEMY 1 4
FINISH
```

DEO realizes that in round 1, enemy played at least $20, due to level change. And he noticed that in round 2, enemy played 1 digit number. DEO taught that WORLD decides to save his money and invest $0. DEO decides to invest $1

WORLD invests $0 while DEO invests $1. Since DEO invests more money then WORLD, DEO win 1 point.

And so on

Comment: what happens if both players invest the same number of points? Also, it seems you could guarantee a tie as player 1 by investing 0 in the first round (guaranteed loss/tie the round), then investing 99 the second round (guaranteed win/tie the round).

Comment: @stokastic None wins the round. You do realize that you need that it's best of 9. So if I follow your strategy, I will get 1 point by round 2, however, my opponent easily wins the next 5 and end the game (since I already use all of my 99 ).

Answer (score 0):

## My telephone is a computer!

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

I finally took the plunge and purchased a push-button telephone. It seemed a waste to just bin the old telephone, so I got working with some surplus chips and boards and things, and a soldering iron, and made it into a computer!

Now I need a program. **DialCode(c)** can do Prime Numbers! I think.

So I need some help with an algorithm for Prime Numbers, with the following limitations:

10 variables, which can contain any number from zero upwards, limited only by 32,767; (Var0 - Var9)

10 labels; (Label0 - Label9)

10 Machine Instructions;

```
EndBlock: Ends a block - if the block was actioned, implicity Continue Main is executed, 
otherwise continues with next instruction (EndBlock) 

Test > 0: Starts a block, can test multiple variables (If > 0 Var0 ...)

Test = 0: Starts a block, can test multiple variables (If = 0 Var0 ...)
 
Set variable to another variable (Var0 = Var1)

Set variable to 1 (Var0 = 1)

Set variable to 0 (Var0 = 0)

Increment variable by 1 (Var0 +)

Decrement variable by 1 (Var0 -)

Unconditional branch to label (Br Label0)

Continue MAIN (Continue MAIN)

Output variable (Output Var0)
```

Instructions prior to the first `Test` are executed only once, at the start of the program.

`Continue MAIN` can be within a block or a "special case" unconditional use which is the target for the completion of a non-nested block.

The first `Test` defines `MAIN`.

`MAIN` is executed an "installation setting" number of times. These are 10 for Testing, and 1,200 for Production.

A `Test` can define an internal block if appearing before an `EndBlock`. The completion of an internal block does not cause automatic iteration (but an explicit Continue MAIN can be used for that).

All variables are initially zero.

Example program

```
Var1 = 1 
If > 0 Var1 Var3 
    Var2 +
EndBlock
If > 0 Var2
    Var1 +
    Var3 +
EndBlock
Var2 +
Continue MAIN
Output Var1
Output Var2
Output Var3
```

`MAIN` is defined here by the first `IF > 0`. The first test is not true. The second test is not true. `Var2` gets one added, and `MAIN` starts up again (the unconditional `Continue MAIN`). The first test is still not true. The second test is now true, and `Var1` and `Var3` get one added. Since the block was executed, there is an implicit `Continue MAIN`. From this point on, the first `IF > 0` will always be true, its block will be executed, with another implicit `Continue MAIN` so the program will finish quickly.

The above program demonstrates how to implement a "case-like" structure. Put another way:

```
Var1 = 1
BlockControl repeat 10 times
  case
    Var1 > 0 And Var3 > 0
      Var2 +
      break
  case
    Var2 > 0
      Var1 +
      Var3 +
      break
  case
    other
      Var2 +
EndBlockControl
Output Var1
Output Var2
Output Var3
```

The output from the program will be 2, 9, 1.

Algorithm can be demonstrated in any language, even pseudo-code (if *guaranteed* to work). Explanations will probably make your Answer more popular.

It is not required to write an emulator of the CPU, only to limit your choice of instructions in your language to those logically equivalent to what is supported by the CPU. **DialCode(c)** itself is a subset of your language (subject to differences in syntax)!

There is no input. Output can be whatever is convenient. Feel free to use any specialist libraries, as long as they follow the above limitations.

The Winner *must work* to the limitations. The most popular working algorithm will be chosen. Where submissions are effectively the same algorithm, the one posted first, which *I* was able to understand, is the tie-breaker.

### Sandbox Questions

I can't find a question here about generating Primes only using addition and subtraction. I know one way to do it, so all the guff above is to funnel thought towards a known solution. The solution I've seen uses 10 variables, 10 or fewer types of instructions, and Labels are fun, but not necessarily necessary.

Not sure of a reasonable time-limit to impose before the Accept.

When I came across an algorithm for this, I thought it was really cool. Very easy to implement without knowing how the algorithm actually works, difficult to come up with the algorithm. Great fun finding out *how* the algorithm works.

I would like to see a wide range of answers in a lot of languages, so that even fairly inexperienced users can have a crack at implementing. That's not going to work with one question, because I don't think it is an easy type of algorithm to develop (without foreknowledge or practice).

So I was thinking one question to get an algorithm, a second question for implementation. I was thinking of "fastest code" but that puts Assembler/compiled languages/others as the natural rankings for that.

Prompted by a comment by @isaacg, I'm now thinking "total number of **DialCode(C)** instructions executed" may work for a follow-up implementation question.

So, Question One - get a nice algorithm. Question Two, implement in as few **DialCode(C)** instructions as possible.

Any implementation is going to be Ssssslllllooooooowwwwww, with a capital S. Fewest **DialCode(C)** instructions is fastest code, whatever language the **DialCode(C)** is written in. Reasonably level playing field.

I'll have a go at the suggested shortening of the question :-)

Comment: I like the challenge, but three comments: 1. The post might be a bit long, try to shorten it up a bit. 2. Why is it a popularity contest? Why not have an objective victory condition, e.g. fewest instructions? 3. What does this have to do with a telephone?

Comment: @isaacg Thanks. In reverser order; the telephone solely as a massively humorous way to limit everything to 10; perhaps not everyone can come up with an/the algorithm, but pretty much anyone can implement the algorithm, I didn't want APL 3 and everyone goes home, I want algorithm, and if successful a follow-up for implementation; if I take the humour out, it should be much shorter...

Comment: Okay, I think I get the humor, and that seems good. Perhaps you could have the tiebreaker between people with the same algorithm be fewer number of operations in your language used, not fewer characters.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks again. I'll update the Sandbox Questions bit to try to expand on my thoughts on the follow-up.

Comment: Awesome, I'm looking forward to the question.

Comment: @isaacg Finally got some time cleared to update this and cover the release. Any further suggestions, more shortening or otherwise, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Traffic lights

### Easy challenge

Write a program that that graphically shows traffic lights on a crossroads. It should output animation. There should be red, red+yellow, green, blinking green, yellow. Bonus - pedestrian traffic light.

### Complex challenge

Write a program that manages traffic lights in a town. Input is a graph of roads, information about where people want to drive (i.e. in morning they mostly drive at work, in evening they return home) tied to the graph.
The system models cars and reports you current positions and speeds of each car. Drivers' goals are to be inferred from statistics. Your goal is to provide the most optimal operation mode of each individual traffic light, avoiding accidents.

### Questions

- Which tags to use? Should it be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
- Which is more viable - the easy or the complicated challenge? Should I try to work the complicated one to be more CodeGolf-worthy?

Comment: I think both of these challenges are too vague for this site. In the first, you should provide precise requirements defining a 'traffic light.' For example, the cloud in [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38093/31625) is extremely well defined. Your second proposal could work as a [tag:code-challenge], again if you add much more precise requirements.

Comment: I see you're from Belarus. You have blinking green traffic lights there? I've not seen them in any of the 5 countries I've lived in. Don't assume people will know the exact sequence you want to use. Also in the USA you can turn right on a red light, but in western europe I've never heard of this. I would go for the easy challenge first, but you need to specify it more. How should it be displayed (I'm assuming plan view, light drawn on the right hand side of the road as seen by the driver with red nearest the intersection?) Is there a specified timed sequence or does it depend on demand?

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea for an incremental answer-dependent question. I'm interested in comments. I will keep it here for a while and probably reword it at some point.

---

## Print the name of the language of the previous answer

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The first answer to this question must print the name `Code-Golf` without using any letters in `Code-Golf`.

Each answer that follows will have to print the name of the previous language, but without using any characters in the previous program (you can use letters in the language name, but not the code they posted). Each language can only be used once.

The winner is whoever posts the most valid answers. If there is a tie, then the length of each program is added together, and the answerer with the smallest total length is the winner.

---

The main problem I see with this is that multiple people would be racing towards the next answer. Allowing people to still post answers they worked on would cause clutter, and if people sign up to be the next answerer, we could be waiting forever for one to post. You could possibly have another question for answers that were too slow.

I would also need a rule against posting extraneous characters in your program that makes it impossible for the next one.

Comment: Would repeating languages be allowed? Would there be an answer time limit for users? Is Unicode allowed? You could limit answers to 40 distinct chars instead of forbidding extraneous characters, which is very subjective.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I like the 40 distinct character limit idea! Repeating languages is not allowed, and I don't know what would be a good time limit for users. I think allowing Unicoding makes sense, unless that could be abused badly or gets boring. Thanks for the feedback! Did 8 hours feel too long or too short or just right on your Hello World question?

Comment: I think it should be at least 2 hours. Though 8 or higher is better if you're scoring by number of answers, just so people only have to post a couple times a day to be a contender. One issue with this is that even with 40 unique chars it could continue on practically forever (as long as people [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) new languages), so I'd suggest more restrictions. Maybe something like `the first language has to start with "A" the second with "B", the 26th with "Z" the 27th with "A" again...`.

Answer (score 0):

## Elevator Controller

---

### Sandbox Note

- I would love some feedback about whether you think this has enough room for algorithmic finesse to stick with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) or whether it should be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- Any kind of early questions or ideas are welcome, too.

---

### Introduction

Every day on my way to work I have to take one of two neighboring elevators – and often, they are not currently on my floor, so I have to press a button and wait for it to stop by. Ever so often, I get the feeling the software behind these elevators was written by an army of monkeys who finally managed to type *some* program that would compile.

But it makes me think: isn't there a more clever way to manage elevators? Maybe you can help me make my way to work less annoying by implementing a new controller software!

### The Challenge

You must write a complete program that takes input from stdin (or similar) and print to stdout (or similar). Your program will receive the following arguments:

- The first line consists of two **space**-separated numbers:

  - The number `N` of neighboring elevators your software will have to manage.
  - One integer `H` specifying the number of the top floor level for the building (the ground floor level is marked `0`, so `H = 5` means there are six stories).
- All subsequent lines of input are a **space**-separated list of two numbers in the range `[0, H]` with the following meaning:

  - The first integer specifies the level on which a passenger is requesting an elevator.
  - The second integer specifies the level this passenger would like to get to.

During each time tick, your program must print (to stdout or similar) one line with `N` characters wherein each character specifies what an elevator does (from left to right = first to last elevator). The following commands are available:

- `D` for "Move elevator one level **d**own."
- `U` for "Move elevator one level **u**p."
- `S` for "**S**top the elevator on this level." This command allows any number of passengers to enter or exit the elevator on this level. This will happen automatically and people will only exit the elevator on the level they want to get to.

Furthermore, all elevators are rather small and have a maximum capacity of `2` people. So no elevator can take more than two people. Since people are generally nice, they apply a *first come, first serve* pattern. Passengers who are "too many" will just wait the next turn.

If two (or more) elevators happen to stop on the same level with people waiting to enter, they will start filling up the elevators from left to right.

All `N` elevators will start on the ground level – `0` – upon start of the program.

As always, standard loopholes apply. No cheating, no networking etc. If possible, please submit your answer with a link to an online interpreter or instructions on how to run it.

### Example

Input:

```
2 3
2 0
3 1
```

Possible Output:

```
UU
UU
SU
DS
DD
SD
SS
```

Here are more examples, but to keep the post short, newlines are represented as `|` and input/output is separated by `#`:

```
2 3|0 1|0 2|0 3 # SS|UU|SU|UU|SS|US|SS

1 2|0 1|1 2|1 0|1 0 # S|U|S|U|S|D|S|D|S
```

### Scoring

This is a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). There will be an unknown test case which I will only reveal after having accepted the winning answer (so you can make sure I didn't make scores up), but not before as to prevent answers optimizing for that test case only.

The score will be the number of steps your submission prints (= number of lines of your program's output). The lowest score wins with votes as a tiebreaker.

### Verification

You may use the following snippet to verify your submission:

TODO (I will write this once I plan on publishing this question)

Answer (score 0):

**The Invincible Rock Paper Scissors**

[underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Make a bot that plays Rock Paper Scissors with the player. The bot should prompt the user for input (either `rock`, `paper`, or `scissors`) and then output the result. The result should include the user's hand, the bot's hand, and who won. An example of an acceptable result output would thus be:

```
I played rock! You played scissors! I won!
```

Another acceptable output:

```
The bot's rock beat the player's scissors.
```

This is the underhanded part: the bot should *always win*. However, the player has access to the source code of the program, so you should try and make the part of the code that causes the bot to always win as inconspicious as possible.

Here is an example in Python 2.x. If it were posted, it would not get many upvotes because it is extremely obvious that the bot will always win. A better answer would appear to be fair to the player, but in fact still causes the bot to win every time.

```
user_choice = raw_input("Pick a hand (rock, paper, or scissors)...")
if user_choice == "rock":
    print "I played paper! You played rock! I won!"
elif user_choice == "paper":
    print "I played scissors! You played paper! I won!"
elif user_choice == "scissors":
    print "I played rock! You played scissors! I won!"
```

**Concerns**

My main concern with this challenge is that it may be a close duplicate of [random script that isn't actually random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31836/21682). I am not sure if the requirement for having a different output for the user's input (while maintaining the illusion of randomness) is enough to differentiate this challenge from the original underhanded random challenge. Feedback on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, "underhanded" does not imply "always win."  I think there are many more options for underhanded behaviors.  For example, someone could write a RPS program with a weakness to be exploited by those with "insider info."  That can help this challenge avoid being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

## N-gon Naming

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

### Challenge

Given the word name of a polygon `n`, you must output the number of sides polygon `n`.

### Examples

```
Input:  triangle
Output: 3

Input:  dodecagon
Output: 12

Input:  megagon
Output: 1000000

Input:  hexahexagon
Output: 66
```

### Winning

The shortest code wins.

The list of shape names can be found [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Naming_polygons) with instructions on how shape names are constructed. Use the alkane naming system.

Comment: In case you aren't aware, there's a pretty simple [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number#Formula) to find these numbers.

Comment: @Geobits This is more parsing of the shape name

Comment: For some reason I thought that part was a dupe, but it turns out I can't find anything except going the other way (3->tri).

Comment: You'll probably need to define an upper limit, like [this question did](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40523/31625)

Comment: If the challenge is really about parsing the shape name, then just have that be the question.

Comment: It might be a good idea to point out if we need to support `Tetracontadigon`, as well as `42-gon`.

Comment: The rules on that new link are confusing. What is a `hexahectogon`? `6100`? `600`?

Comment: Can we really trust a site that says `Is there actually a name for a 27 sided pentagon? Yes there is.`?

Comment: @feersum Yeah... I was hoping to find a long list of every shape from 3 to n... That's the best I could do ATM

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon has a better list with more rules than the site you linked. Anyway, both sites offer various alternative names and you should specify which are required, and the maximum number of sides to be supported. It is very, very unclear how a polygon with more than 1999 sides should be named.

Comment: @steveverrill A polygon with more than 1999 sides -> circle ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Lua Variables From Arguments?**

In this question I challenge you to get variables from function arguments in Lua. The least amount of characters wins.

Basically I'm asking for you to create a function that takes an argument, and prints out the variable as a string.

*Please note it has to work in a standalone Lua console.*

Comment: I don't know Lua, but I have no idea what this is asking. Do we need to extract the names of the arguments? Their values? You will probably benefit from including an example input/output for this program/function...

Comment: @Fry The variable, for example function hello(m) print(m) end m is an argument, the variable *is* m.

Comment: @warspyking This definitely needs a proper spec. I do know a little Lua, but I'm still not sure what you're asking for. Please provide examples. Also, I should warn you that language-specific challenges are usually frowned upon, unless there are some reasons why the challenge only makes sense in that particular language (which I can't tell yet).

Comment: OK, so that is still quite ambiguous: do you mean for us to get a reference to the variable? You need to tell us _precisely_ where we get the information from (STDIN, file, etc) and _precisely_ where and how to output it in the question. As it stands, this would be closed as unclear if posted.

Comment: @Martin Why is language specific questions frowned upon?

Comment: @Fry I added a little more detail in.

Comment: @warspyking Because most of the time, there's no good reason to exclude people from your challenge you don't happen to know the same programming language as you (and quite often, language-specific challenges are a good indicator that someone's trying to use PPCG to outsource their homework, although that's probably not the case here). So if this challenge makes sense in other languages, you should try to be inclusive. And you should really add an example to show us what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @Martin I don't know any other language to be able to confirm the answer.

Comment: @warspyking If you added an example, some people might be able to tell you. ;)

Comment: If I understand the refined question correctly, the goal is to retrieve the parameter names for the parameters of a function from inside the function itself, using reflection-style capabilities.  With some help, I think that could be turned into something language-agnostic (though it'd need some good way of disallowing hardcoded results).

Comment: @FireFly Yep, you've understood it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## Break out of the digital world!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [back-to-reality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-to-reality)

***Note:*** The tag [back-to-reality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-to-reality) is just something I knocked up quickly, if anyone has any better ideas please let me know.

### Challenge

You must write a morse code to ASCII translator using an external device (such as a button or the spacebar on the keyboard).

#### Dots

A button press is a dot when it has been pressed for 0.5 seconds or longer and released.

#### Dashes

A button press is a dash when it has been pressed for 1 second or longer and released.

#### Exit

A button press is an exit when it has been pressed for 5 seconds or more. This should end the program and display the result.

#### Space

A space is when there has been no button input for 1 second. This should move on to the next letter.

Your code should support every character on the following:

http://zunkworks.com/images/bluetoothmorse/morsecode1.gif

### Winning

The shortest code wins. You may write this in any language that allows input from an external source. For example, Arduino or Python (on a Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Does this actually have to be able take input from hardware? Can you allow feeding in simulating data? I think a standard format like a sequence of numbers measuring current/voltage every millisecond would make it more accessible.

Comment: While I do own an arduino, I see absolutely no reason why this challenge should be limited to using an external switch. Is there anything wrong with using the space bar or a mouse button? If it HAS to be an external switch, how about I rip open my mouse and connect an old doorbell push  across one of the mouse button contacts?

Answer (score 0):

### Number Datasheets [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program that accepts an integer `n` where `1 < n < 10000` and prints some facts about it. Each fact must be on a separate line, and in the order shown here.

- `even` or `odd`
- `prime` or `composite`
- `deficient`, `perfect`, or `abundant`
- `square` if it's a perfect square
- `cube` if it's a perfect third power
- `fourth power` if it's a perfect fourth power
- `fifth power`, `sixth power`, etc. as appropriate (each on a separate line)
- `square-free` if it has no factors that are perfect squares (except 1)
- `triangular` if it's a triangular number
- `pentagonal` if it's a pentagonal number
- `hexagonal`, `heptagonal`, `octagonal`, `nonagonal`, `decagonal` as appropriat
- `11-gonal`, `12-gonal` ... `k-gonal`. However, these should only be printed if `k` is less than `n` or if `k` is less than 10. In any event, each of these term is to be on a separate line.
- `x totatives` where `x` is the count of the numbers between 0 and `n` that are coprime to `n`
- `lucky` if it's a lucky number
- `Fibonacci` if it's a Fibonacci number
- `Lucas` if it's a Lucas number
- `Leonardo` if it's a Leonardo number
- `repdigit in base b` if it's a repdigit in base `b`, where `1 < b < n-1`

  - If it's a repdigit in multiple such bases, instead print `repdigit in base b, c, d`
- `strictly non-palindromic` if it's not a palindrome in any base `b` where `1 < b < n-1`

*Any feedback would be appreciated.*

Comment: Needs more links. I'd remove the polygonal numbers - that's a lot of hard-coded names to effectively duplicate [your earlier question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37232/194).

Comment: How many powers do we need to support? And are empty lines in the output allowed?

Comment: I think you're asking for too many things. I wouldn't want to code all those different properties. Maybe cut down to about 5?

Comment: I agree with xnor that there's too many things here. Regarding @MartinBüttner's comment, the first thing I would change is limit the powers to no more than cube, and polygonal numbers to no more than triangular. You need to clearly define all the different types of number too. There's a difference between polygonal numbers and centred polygonal numbers that would need to be clarified. Off the top of my head I have no idea what lucas and leonardo numbers are

Answer (score 0):

**Math golf**

This challenge is about writing code that outputs the smallest formula possible for a sequence of position integers.

**Input**

I will choose 10 from the following test sequences of positive integers. However, please do not hardcode these into your answers. If I suspect this has happened, I reserve the right to change the test sequences without notice.

Your code should accept standard in with one list of comma separated sequences per line.

> 1, 2, 7
>
> 12, 9, 7, 5
>
> 40, 25, 16, 10, 7
>
> 2240, 1225, 679, 373, 213, 149, 141, 133
>
> 8064, 3969, 1969, 974, 494, 254, 164, 134, 119
>
> 118272, 53361, 24196, 10958, 5027, 2399, 1271, 863, 746, 695, 668, 665
>
> 1, 4, 36, 400, 4900
>
> 96, 1280, 17920, 258048, 3784704, 56229888, 843448320
>
> 72, 800, 9800, 127008, 1707552, 23557248, 331273800
>
> 40, 224, 1064, 3808,  21280, 59200, 322600
>
> 2240,  832,  240,   72,   20,    6,    3
>
> 53760, 17152,  4480,  1248,   384,   104,    44,    22,    11
>
> 329472,  86656,  20800,   5536,   1536,    440,    124,     44,         19,      8,      4
>
> 32800768,  6856704,  1536000,   394752,   103936,    27136,           7936,     2080,      656,      264,      132,       66,       33
>
> 206389248,  33216512,   7029760,   1743360,    448000,    112640,  30144,      8288,      2096,       688,       284,       102,      46,        18,         9
>
> 20956446720,  2527756288,   510181376,   122363904,    30720000,      7643136,     1972224,      508416,      136192,       35456,             10816,        3296,        1360,         632,         292,               146,          73

**Output**

A math formula per input line which maps an index `n` starting at `1` to the relevant value.

A formula can be made up as follows. It can consist of the sequence variable `n`, integer constants, `*`, `/`, `-`, `+`, `!`, `(`, `)`, `^` or `(m,k)`.  These are to be interpreted in their normal mathematical sense with `(m,k)` to be read as `binomial(m,k)`.  The formula has to be well formed with, for example, parentheses matching and the order of precedence of operators will be the usual mathematical ordering.

A special rule applies to the factorial function `!` which requires parentheses if the `^` or `!`  operators are to be applied to the result of the factorial. I.e. it is `(n!)^2` and not `n!^2`. Note that the `!!` is never allowed.  Unary `-` also requires brackets if any further operator is applied to the result on the left hand side or if the result is to be raised to a power. For example it is `n*(-1)` and not `n*-1`.

**Score**

I will test your code on a number of sequences of integers that I make.

The score is the sum of the number of characters in all your outputs.

**Example output**

For the sequence that starts `96, 1280` above, the output `4^(n+1)*(2*(n+1))!/((n+1)!)^2` gives a score of `29`.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it sounds brutally hard in the absence of gimmicks. There is, generally speaking, no systematic or efficient procedure for turning a sequence of numbers into a formula.

Comment: There's always the polynomial of degree length-1... which is the only realistic option if you write something longer than 10 characters. One could try to golf the polynomial a bit but anyway it wouldn't be a great challenge.

Comment: @feersum and COTO , The challenge is interesting, I hope, if many of the test cases come from sequences which do have short formulae. You are right that if the sequences are genuinely chosen at random it is perhaps not so interesting.

Answer (score 0):

## Generalized Array Indexing

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

Most programming languages provide an array datatype (which might be called a list or a vector) that supports indexing. Given an array and a nonnegative integer, we can fetch the element of the array at that position: `[a,b,c][0] = a`. Some languages, like Python, support a more general indexing system, where passing a negative index counts the position from the end: `[a,b,c][-1] = c`. But why stop there?

In this challenge, your task is to provide another generalization of this operation. In other words, you must provide a function that takes in an array and a number, and returns *something*, up to the following restrictions:

1. If a nonnegative integer is passed to the function, it must return the element of the array at that position. In other words, it must be an extension of the array indexing operation.
2. It must support more indices than just nonnegative integers, like negative integers, fractions, complex numbers, or even strings. In other words, it must be a proper extension.

If necessary, you may restrict the types of elements your arrays may contain, so you may choose to only handle arrays of, say, floating-point numbers, or other arrays. This is a popularity contest, so the answer with the most upvotes wins.

Comment: I'm sure people would come up with some fun ideas, but I believe this is currently a bit too broad as it stands (the telltale sign being a "something" in italics in your spec).

Comment: That was my fear too. I don't know whether this can be turned into a good challenge without changing the idea completely, but I'll leave it here for now.

Answer (score 0):

## Play Chopsticks

**Disclaimer**: Please fix the question and the scoring if they are not satisfactory. I am probably not qualified to run and score entries because I am not entirely familiar with the logistics of running two programs against one another, and, as such, **I will not be posting this question to the main page myself**. So, if anyone wants to take this off my hands, feel free. I just really like this idea and want to see it happen.

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[Chopsticks Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopsticks_%28hand_game%29)

Your challenge is to write a program that, given the current position of the game as input (how many fingers on each hand), outputs the next move it chose to take.

### Rules of the game

(Normal rules, no variations)

1. When a hand's finger-count becomes >= 5, it's finger-count becomes 0.
2. Splitting/transferring is allowed. You CAN bring a dead hand back by transferring some fingers from your other hand.
3. However, splitting/transferring is not allowed if the move only results in you having swapped your hands. (eg. no prolonging the game by "doing nothing")
4. A player loses if both their hands are dead.

### Input

You will receive as input the number of fingers on each of your and your opponents hands.

Input will be given in the following format:

```
#_on_your_LH #_on_your_RH #_on_opponent_LH #_on_opponent_RH
```

Examples:

```
1 1 1 1
```

or

```
4 0 3 2
```

### Output

Your program will output your move base on the input.

**Key**:

```
First number:
  0 (your LH)
  1 (your RH)
  2 (transfer from your LH to your RH)
  3 (transfer from your RH to your LH)

Second number:
  If first number was 0 or 1:
    0 (opponent's LH)
    1 (opponent's RH)
  If first number was 2 or 3:
    1-3 (# of fingers to transfer)
```

Examples:

```
0 0 (tap opponent's RH with your LH)
0 1 (tap opponent's LH with your LH)
1 0 (tap opponent's RH with your RH)
1 1 (tap opponent's LH with your RH)
2 1 (transfer 1 finger from your LH to your RH)
3 2 (transfer 2 fingers from your RH to your LH)
```

### Scoring

Each entry will be made to play a game against every other entry.
If a game does not end after 100 rounds (?), it will be declared a tie.

Two points will be awarded for every win and one point will be awarded for every tie.
Entry with the most points is the king of the chopstick-hill.

Comment: This sounds so familiar, I feel like it has been posted before, either on main or in the sandbox (or maybe it was just discussed in chat), but the game has so many names that it's hard to find right now. (Looks like it was the sandbox and died off right away: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17654246#17654246)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I still think that this should be done. Perhaps it could be made more interesting by allowing the programs to see the whole game, not just on a turn-by-turn basis, and they then could adapt to their opponents. Though I believe that would require networking / competing on a server, of which I know little. Well, in any case, like I said, I just thought this was a good idea and wanted to see it happen, though I don't feel up to taking the responsibility to do it myself. If this dies off too... oh well.

Comment: I'm not sure if I remembered right, but I thought Chopsticks was a solved game for the second player?

Comment: @Sp3000 Dang it. I think you're right. I wonder if any of the variations to the game change it enough for it to require more strategy and not be a solved game.

Answer (score 0):

## Help Bob the Builder survive the communists, and fast!

The communists have taken over the world and you are the last remaining tower builder.
In order to surive you must show that you are able to build towers and fast!

### The challenge

Bob is given a set of building blocks `b`, and a number `n` of towers to build. Since we are in communist land the towers should have as equal of an height as possible. The catch is that you are only given 180 seconds to build the towers. The goal is to minimize the `std` of the tower height. In addition you have to build towers at *three* different sites. Which means three different sets of building blocks and three different set of towers.

### Input & Output

```
blocks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
towers = 3
```

The ouput should be on the form

```
7 6 2
8 5 4
1 9 5

std = 0
```

Here the towers are built vertically. The std is calculated as follows

```
std = sqrt[(mean - tower1)^2 + (mean - tower2)^2 + ...]
```

where tower1 represents the height of that tower and mean is the average of the heights.

```
mean = (tower1 + tower2 + ... + towern)/towers
```

## Example 2

Input

```
blocks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
towers = 2
```

Output

```
5 3 2 4 1
9 6 7 9 0

std = 0.7071
```

Since mean = (23+22)/2 = 22.5 and std = [(22.5-23)^2+(22-23)^2]^(1/2) = [1/4+1/4]^(1/2) = (1/2)^1/2.

These two are examples of optimal outputs. Since the problem is NP hard an optimal solution within a reasonable time is impossible.

## Scoring

The blocks for the three building sizes are given below. The sum of these three tests judge your performance. *Lowest score wins*. Eg

```
 score = 100*std(1) + 50*std(2) + std(3)
```

Where std stands for the standard deviation obtained at building site `n`. Do not try to cheat and make a code that runs longer than 300 seconds. The KGB (Eg me) performs regurarly controls.

---

## Question for meta

1) Is the problem clear enough? Eg use the three vectors and distribute them equally

2) Is the scoring now fair? Must have a run time beneath 3 minutes, lowest score wins.

[Building site 1:  2 towers](http://pastebin.com/aWavj5df)

[Building site 2:  3 towers](http://pastebin.com/LZD4cYNv)

[Building site 3: 23 towers](http://pastebin.com/9UcijnmP)

Comment: How is this different to [your previous question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42195/194)?

Comment: In previous question the number of elements in each tower were fixed, here only the number of towers are fixed. There is now a logical time constraint as well as a fair score system. Plus slightly more creative vectors. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

## Quine is love, quine is life (well, almost)

Yes, another Life challenge. Inspired by [this](http://igoro.com/archive/self-printing-game-of-life-in-c/).

## Challenge

Write a program (the **generator**) that, when given a representation of a Game of Life board on STDIN (or in a file if you like), outputs a program which contains a string representation of a Game of Life board in its source code.

The representation will be in the following format:

```
 h w x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 . . . xw yh
```

where:

- `h` = height of the grid
- `w` = width of the grid
- `xi yi` = coordinates of a live cell

When run, the new program should output its own source code - with a catch: the string in the output must represent the generation following the one previously encoded. (We shall call this program the **replicator**.)

## Other stuff

- All live cells will be provided as input, so all other cells may be assumed to be dead.
- `0,0` is at the **bottom left**.
- Both programs (the generator and the replicator) **need not be in the same language**.
- There may be a width-one border around the string representation for a **-10% bonus in score**.

## Scoring

Your score on a particular input will be defined as **the length of the generator plus the average length of the first 100 generations of the replicator**.

Your final score will be the average of your scores on all the test cases.
The lowest score wins!

---

## Question

Should we impose a format for the string representation, like maybe

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*                                   *
*                                   *
*                 *                 *
*               *                   *
*               * * *               *
*                                   *
*                                   *
*                                   *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

or should we let the GolfScripters and CJammers of PPCG use their unprintable black magic? :D

Comment: Just to check, the scoring formula is `generator_length + sum(replicator_lengths)/100`? The bolding is a tad misleading: it seems to imply that the division is performed also on the generator length (which would be very odd).

Comment: That is indeed what I meant, but you're right; it is a bit odd. Fixing.

Comment: The scoring formula is `generator_length + sum(lengths of first 100 replicators)/100`.

Comment: This looks like a less interesting version of [this Life quine question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35974/194). If you do decide to allow flexibility in the representation, you'll need to be careful to avoiding being too close a duplicate. Other than that, I don't understand what `h` and `w` are (is there an unspoken assumption of boundary conditions?) nor what you mean about `0,0` being the bottom left (since the output doesn't care which directions the axes run) or about having a border around the string representation.

Answer (score 0):

### Query the icosahedral graph

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You've been sent back in time to 1973 to change history by remaking a clone of [Hunt the Wumpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus). You need to code a network of rooms in the game that forms an [icosahedral graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosahedralGraph.html), whose vertices correspond to the 12 vertices of the [icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron) connected by edges, unlike the [dodecahedral graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DodecahedralGraph.html) used in the original game. Each room connects to five others.

Your goal is to write a program or function that takes the ID numbers of two of the twelve rooms, and returns one value if the rooms are adjacent, and a different value if not. Due to space constraints, you code needs to use as few bytes as possible.

You can choose what ID's to label the 12 rooms, but due to hardware constraints, they must be numbers from 0 to 255. Specifying the ID's doesn't count for the code length.

**Input**

Two distinct ID numbers from 0 to 255 out of 20 of your choice. You can't restrict which order two numbers appear in.

**Output**

A consistent value for pairs of numbers that correspond to adjacent rooms in your ID scheme, and a different consistent value for non-adjacent pairs.

Your code may not use any built-ins that represent the dodecahdral graph or related structures.

Comment: I haven't actually given much thought to how to do this and how hard or easy this easy. Looking for feedback on this half-baked idea.

Comment: Well, [Hunt the Wumpus has been done](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26128/8478). Not sure how much more room for variation this subchallenge gives other than ripping out the relevant parts from the answers of the previous challenge.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Fair point, I'll switch to a different graph.

Comment: I'm not sure at the moment which graph the question is trying to talk about, but IIRC both dodecahedron and icosahedron have been done. In fact, [you did a dodecahedron graph structure question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35978/194) already.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess I'm not conveying my idea well. The core idea is to make a two-input function whose truth table is isomorphic to some specific graph, with you getting to choose the input labels and the isomorphism. So, it's a question of how to represent the required graph as much as how to code it. For example, if I asked to make a 16-vertex hypercube graph, you could label vertices by the four-bits numbers 0 to 16 the natural way, and check for an edge by whether the xor of the two labels is a power of 2.

Comment: I understood that. How do you feel about switching to the Petersen graph? It's comparable in size and complexity, but it's definitely not treading on the toes of the previous questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The Petersen graph happens to have a compact and elegant solution that's surely optimal. Got any other graphs to suggest?

Comment: Fair point. How about the McGee graph? It's not vertex-transitive, so I think that probably forces a different approach to the group representational approach which was used on the earlier questions. Other interesting options might be the Pappus graph and the Coxeter graph, but they have more symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

## Reverse Polish Notation-ing!

Your challenge is simply to write a function which converts a given arithmetical expression into it's [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) form.

### Input

Your function will be passed in an arithmetical expression, as a string, which may contain any of `+-*/^()` or a space. For example:

`1+1
34 * 7^6
3 * (78 + 7)`

### Output

Your function should return the Reverse Polish Notation form of the input with a space between each number. The above inputs would output:

`1 1 +
7 6 ^ 34 *
78 7 + 3 *`

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins. Bonuses are as follows:

- -15 for supporting brackets in the input (as in: `()`)
- -5 for supporting exponents (as in: `^`)
- -10 for supporting floating point (decimal) numbers (formatted with a dot: `12.56`)

You should support, at minimum, `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operations.

Good luck!

---

*To the sandbox*:

- *Should I give more examples or is 3 enough?*
- *Do you think the deductions are a fair amount off? Too much? Too little?*
- *Am I missing something really obvious? (I usually am!)*

Comment: I would call the inputs arithmetical expressions instead of sums, since there can be other operations than addition.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't think of a better word! Edited :)

Comment: [Looks like it's a duplicate.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5839/8478)

Comment: Gah! Thanks, Nevermind then :(

Answer (score 0):

Print the Twelve Days of Christmas with twelve programming languages

Use twelve programming or scripting languages to write twelve programs, embedded within each other, to print the lyrics for **Twelve Days of Christmas**.

Each program will write the next program to file, compile if needed, and execute it. The parent processes will not exit until the last has executed. When 
they exit, they will print the final verse, program by program. You may only have one file to start with. You may also, optionally, have a text file with each line of the song in it.

You must specifiy any dependencies needed to run the programs. For example, if you need a compiler, such as GCC, or PHP or the Java compiler/Java, put them 
in a list of dependencies.

For example:

```
<?php
echo "On the first day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:\nA partridge in a pear tree!\n";
$code = <<<EOD
public static void main(String [ ] args) {

String nextCode = new String;
System.out.println("On the second day of Christmas, my true love sent to me:");
System.out.print("Two Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n");
nextCode = "(Next code to be written is in here)";
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("thirdDay.c", "UTF-8");
/*
* and write the next program, in this case, thirdDay.c to file and so on....
*/
}
EOD;
file_put_contents("secondDay.java", $code);
exec("javac secondDay.java");
echo exec("java secondDay");
echo "and a Partridge in a pear tree"; // runs after the other twelve have run
?>
```

Apologies for my rusty Java.

To reiterate:

1. The program is started
2. The program prints the appropriate verse
3. The program writes the source code for the next program to file, which in turn contains the code for the rest, and so on.
4. The program compiles (if needed) the next program, and runs it.

The final program will only print the line for Day 12. It will then exit, returning to its parent program, which will print the second line - Day 11, exit, and so on. In my example, this line will run last:

```
echo "and a Partridge in a pear tree"; // runs after the other twelve have run
```

Have fun with those quote marks. I started with PHP and Heredoc for a reason ;)

Assume that this will be run in a Linux/Unix terminal. Windows is okay if you can pull it off.

This is a popularity contest. Assuming that you can get everything escaped properly ;)

Merry Christmas!

Comment: My comments on self-contradiction from the original question still stand.

Comment: I'll edit it later, but since it's past Christmas, it's got lower priority now. Can you provide an example of self-contradiction? Perhaps I can remove the offending part to clear it up. (While the first 11 print the full song until day x, number twelve only prints its first line (Partridge) and then exits, sub-program number eleven then prints Turtle doves, exits, and so on until the original program.)

Comment: "*It's not clear whether the final output should be the full lyrics of the song (one verse per program) or just the last verse (one line per program); or whether each program in the chain should print then execute (as per example code and numbered breakdown) or execute and then print (as per "*It will then exit, returning to its parent program, which will print Day 11, exit, and so on*")*"

Answer (score 0):

## The Great, White, North! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - [POSTED](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44757/the-great-white-north)

Comment: 1. What are the bounds on the relative proportions? 2. What are the RGB codes of the colours? 3. What are the minimum dimensions? 4. What's to stop me using a font which is so different that only I can read it? 5. Does "saves an image" include "writes an image on stdout"?

Comment: Since [there is no clear consensus on this yet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3610/8478) you might want to mention explicitly whether you will allow golfed/compressed raw image files as submissions.

Comment: In-universe note: You should probably just save a highly compressed image instead of a program to produce the image. You might then be able to squeeze another syrup recipe on there (or a script to curl the latest hockey scores).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Been almost two weeks but I finally revamped it. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I was travelling. Looks like you sorted all the issues I raised, though.

Answer (score 0):

## A natural divisor

Expressiveness, natural language elements and readability, these are just a few of the awesome features/ideologies modern high-level languages promise us. But how "readable" and "natural" are these languages really? Can you really read them as they were english? In this challenge you have to prove how (un)natural your preferred language really is.

### Challenge

You're to write a program that accepts a list/string of numbers from the STDIN, and outputs their [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) to the STDOUT. However you also need to write a complete description of your program, an english explanation of your entire program. The challenge is to make your program resemble the description as much as possible. As in a perfect natural programming language there would be no difference, your score will be the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your program and your description.

### Rules

- Your description can only contain correct english sentences. The sentences must be at least six words long.
- The description must contain the full and correct  process of your program. Nothing more or less. An example can be found below. As a general rule: a programmer that doesn't understand your language should completely understand your description and should be  able to recreate the exact algorithm.
- Your program cannot contain both comments or strings.
- Your program should use [the universal accepted definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestCommonDivisor.html) to calculate the greatest common divisor. If the input only contains `0`'s, you have to output `0`.

### Example

This is a fibonacci function to illustrate how a description should look like:

```
PROGRAM:
def F(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return F(n-1)+F(n-2)

DESCRIPTION:
Define a function F with input n. If n equals 0, return 0. 
Else, if n equals 1, return 1. 
Else, return the output of F with input n minus 1, 
plus the output of F with input n minus 2.
```

### Score

As mentioned earlier, your score is the levenshtein distance between your description and your program. You can calculate your levenshtein distance with the following snippet (thanks doorknob):

```js
var f=document.getElementById("f"),g=document.getElementById("s"); function h(){var a=f.value,e=g.value;if(128<a.length)a="<span style='color:red'>First program is too long!</span>";else if(128<e.length)a="<span style='color:red'>Second program is too long!</span>";else{if(0===a.length)a=e.length;else if(0===e.length)a=a.length;else{var d=[],b;for(b=0;b<=e.length;b++)d[b]=[b];var c;for(c=0;c<=a.length;c++)d[0][c]=c;for(b=1;b<=e.length;b++)for(c=1;c<=a.length;c++)d[b][c]=e.charAt(b-1)===a.charAt(c-1)?d[b-1][c-1]:Math.min(d[b-1][c-1]+1,Math.min(d[b][c-1]+1,d[b-1][c]+ 1));a=d[e.length][a.length]}a="Distance = <strong>"+a+"</strong>"}document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=a}f.onkeyup=h;g.onkeyup=h;
```

```html
<h3 id=ft>program</h3>
<textarea id=f rows=7 cols=80 style="width:100%"></textarea>
<h3 id=st>description</h3>
<textarea id=s rows=7 cols=80 style="width:100%"></textarea>
<p id=d></p>
```

## Sandbox questions/notes:

- The question was just crazy idea for the most part. Do you think this question would work?
- Are there any languages that would get an unfair advantage? Are there more things I should ban?
- I know the description of the program description is somewhat subjective, so the answers would mostly involve being creative with their description. Are their any additional rules that could restrain this?

Comment: The six word restriction seems pretty arbitrary. I might want to write `If so, return 0.` which seems like a perfectly normal sentence in a program description to me. The main trouble will be determining if a description is "good enough". You could do so by defining a vote threshold an answer needs to be eligible, but it's not a perfect solution either. As for the Levenshtein distance, I'm sure Doorknob won't mind you [reusing his Stack Snippet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42910/8478).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I added the six words restriction to avoid one word verbs as a sentence, and force some more verbose description. But I might delete/lower it... A vote threshold is not that bad of an idea actually...

Answer (score 0):

## Final Exam Grade Calculator

So, it's around time for finals, and many students want to know what grade they need on their final exam to achieve an A, B, or sometimes a passing grade. There are many factors here - the weight of the final, two quarters having weight, what grade the students want - but it is still a simple task.

### Objective

Write a program that will take three integers and output the grade they need to receive on the final.

#### Input

Three integers. The first two will be from 0 to 100, and the last will be from 1 to 100. They represent the current score in the class, the desired score, and the weight of the final, respectively. A working example can be found [here](http://rogerhub.com/final-grade-calculator/).

Any input outside the expected ranges can have undefined behavior.

#### Output

The score the student needs to receive on the final exam. This score **could** be above 100 (every once in a while, students have unrealistic expectations), but if it is a negative number, it is automatically 0. The formula for score is as follows.

`(desired - (current score * (1 - weight*.01))) * 100/weight`

The output may not be an integer. In this case, round to the nearest hundredth (round up for .##5).

#### Examples

```
Input: 100 90 20    
50
```

```
Input: 65 60 30
48.33
```

```
Input: 54 100 25
238
```

#### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins.

**Bonuses**

- -10% if your code can take either 3 or 4 integers as input. If four integers are taken, then the first two are averaged to give what would normally be the first integer. Each of the first two integers here represents a quarter grade.

What other bonuses should I add? I can't think of many right now, but even one or two more would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe it's British vs American English, but I find that this question uses some words rather strangely. When the output talks about finding a *score*, that's the word I expect to see in almost every instance of *grade*; I would understand *grade* to mean the letter A, B, etc. That aside, there are some small changes which I think are improvements on either side of the pond: change *expected* to *desired*, and specify with the rounding which way to round `##.##5`. It would probably also be useful to state explicitly that scores are always out of 100.

Comment: Oh, corner cases. Input `80 80 0` is apparently legal, but gives NaN; I would change the spec to say that the weight ranges from 1 to 100. Input `90 80 1` will give a negative number from your formula, but IMO the spec should ask it to be clipped to `0`. You could make that a bonus, but I'd make it a core requirement.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right on everything there. Edge cases will have to be specified. I didn't realize that there were so many. About the wording, I will see what I can do to make it more logical.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible resistances from resistors

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [electrical-engineering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-engineering)

Meta: Note this is far from done; just putting this idea out so that I can continue working on it. IE way work in progress. I need to specify a lot more of this and I'm putting this here because I know I won't end up working on this if it isn't here.

Given a set of resistors, output all the possible resistances that can be formed with them.

Thoughts so far:

## Input:

Input will be a comma-separated **or** space-separated list of natural numbers such as

```
1 4 3 2 4 3 5 999
```

## Output:

Output will be all the possible formable resistances, sorted, on its own lines, plus the number of ways to form each resistance.

(no example yet)

Comment: Sounds like a complicated combinatorial problem wrapped around http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12483/194 . I wouldn't be surprised if you get a few wrong answers and zero correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

## Regex vs HTML

---

As the [Stack Overflowers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3946766) have been defeated, it is up to the Programming Puzzlers and Code Golfers to fight this final battle against the regex-resisting HTML-hordes. Pick up your flavour of choice and join the melee, with the shortest regex you can achieve (no, not like [this](http://pastebin.com/HUmPzP5M))!

### Challenge

Write a regex which takes a html tag, and splits it into `tag name`, `attributes` and `body`. For example, `<img src="something.jpg">caption</img>` is converted to `img`, `src="something.jpg"` and `caption`. Your regex will be run by the controller against a list of tests. Any regex flavour can be used, as long as there is a [driver](https://github.com/matsjoyce/CodeGolf-HtmlRegex/blob/master/drivers/drivers.ini) available (or you want to write your own).

### Rules

- The regex should contain at least 4 groups, one each for tag name, tag attributes, tag body (contents) and a group for the html tag matched, which may be group 0 (which will not add to your regex length).
- Your regex does **not** need to handle all the test cases, but the more handled, the higher your score.
- The scoring formula is `(100 - log(self.length) * 40) * ((passes - total) / total + 1)`, but this will be handled by the scoring program. This formula might change, based on how the challenge progresses. A higher score is better.
- For your regex, you **must** specify the [driver](https://github.com/matsjoyce/CodeGolf-HtmlRegex/blob/master/drivers/drivers.ini) you use (the name in square brackets), any flags and the group names or numbers that hold the split bits. Flags do not contribute towards regex length.

### Testing

- Your program will be run over 30 tests (more may be added) by the [scoring program](https://github.com/matsjoyce/CodeGolf-HtmlRegex), and the number of passes counted.
- Length is in bytes.
- Your score then is `(100 - log(length) * 40) * ((passes - total) / total + 1)`, but this will be handled by the scoring program. This formula might change, based on how the challenge progresses.
- Types of html that you can score points on (remember not all need to be handled):

  - Paired html tags - `<a>b</a>`
  - Tags with the self-closing syntax - `<br/>`
  - Quoted attributes (using either single or double quotes) - `<a href='mysite.com'>b</a>`
  - Unquoted attributes - `<b strength=1>msg</b>`
  - Empty or boolean attributes - `<input disabled/>`
  - Comments (tag name is `!--`, attrs is empty, body is the text of the comment) - `<!-- Something important -->`
  - DOCTYPE sections (tag name is `!DOCTYPE`, body is the following text) - `<!DOCTYPE html>`
  - CDATA sections (tags inside ignored) - `<![CDATA[<br/>]]>`
- Example tests (one on each line, [full list of tests and answers](https://github.com/matsjoyce/CodeGolf-HtmlRegex/blob/master/tests.py)):

  ```
  <a>b</a>
  <a href='mysite.com'>b</a>
  <a href='mysite.com' color="blue" height=1>b</a>
  <quote href="http://somewhere.com">"he said this"</quote>
  <div class="quote">The answer is <div id='the-answer'>42</div></div>
  f'g(<b>x</b>)g'(<b>y</b>)
  <input text='Your name:' focused/>
  ```
- Answers to examples (one on each line):

  ```
  Name   Attrs                                    Body                                         Matched
  =================================================================================================================================================================
  a                                               b                                            <a>b</a>
  a      href='mysite.com'                        b                                            <a href='mysite.com'>b</a>
  a      href='mysite.com' color="blue" height=1  b                                            <a href='mysite.com' color="blue" height=1>b</a>
  quote  href="http://somewhere.com"              "he said this"                               <quote href="http://somewhere.com">"he said this"</quote>
  div    class="quote"                            The answer is <div id='the-answer'>42</div>  <div class="quote">The answer is <div id='the-answer'>42</div></div>
  b                                               x                                            <b>x</b>
  input  text='Your name:' focused                                                             <input text='Your name:' focused/>
  ```
- There is a timeout for the regex matching (currently 5 seconds, but this may change depending on the number of submissions), so if you are making a bit / computationally expensive regex, use a fast driver. The tests will be run on a 2013 MacBook Air, most likely single threaded (although 4 cores are available).

### Drivers

Contributions of drivers is much appreciated. See the [instructions on github.com](https://github.com/matsjoyce/CodeGolf-HtmlRegex/blob/master/README.md#driver-writing).

### Results

```
Name                          Length    Score     Passes    Fails     Timeouts  Errors    
==========================================================================================
Naive                         68        10.6799   12        18        0         0
```

### Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

---

### Sandbox Questions

- Is the scoring formula fair?
- Is this too easy / hard?
- Would abstracting the controller a bit more allow the controller and drivers be useful for scoring other challenges? Would anybody want to use it?
- There is currently a python and a perl driver. Are there any other major regex flavours that should be supported, or should I wait and see until after the sandbox?
- Is there any parts of the challenge that are a bit clunky and need rewriting?
- Could someone add this to the listing at the top?
- Anything I've missed?

Comment: I think this needs the full HTML spec for what a tag can look like. Because [you'd be surprised](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40477/8478)... Also, I'm not a fan of the restriction to a single regex flavour. That's like a language restriction in any other challenge, and usually not a good idea.

Comment: In particular (afaik) it doesn't cover the interesting ones, like recursion and balancing group. But mainly, I just think it's gonna put off people who don't know the flavour (even if it's similar to theirs), because they'll have to look it up.

Comment: When you say "HTML", what do you mean? IMO this would be a much more reasonable challenge if you restrict it to XHTML and thus remove the need to handle auto-closing `<li>`, `<p>`, etc. tags. I agree with @MartinBüttner that some formal spec would be useful, because although the example he links to is invalid, the fact that Optimizer got away with claiming that it was valid suggests that other people may try similar nonsense.

Comment: I have nowhere in my answer mentioned that my answer is following proper HTML W3C spec. Instead, my answer was more on using the loose behavior of browsers parsing an HTML page.

Comment: The edits still don't address the biggest problem with this question, which is a failure to state which HTML spec to follow. Adding a set of test cases doesn't really finesse that, especially since you say that you may add test cases later.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is that better?

Comment: The note to self indicates that you're specifically after HTML5 syntax. If you state that explicitly in the question itself then I will be perfectly satisfied.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, it's HTML 5 syntax without the optional tags section. I listed those under the testing section.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement the Henkin quantifier

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [logic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)

Your goal is to implement the [Henkin quantifier Q_H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_quantifier), a generalized (branching) quantifier on four variables `x1,x2,y1,y2` and a Boolean function `f`. It expresses the idea that for every choice of the `x`'s, there's a choice of the `y`'s so that the four variables satisfy `f`, so that each `y` depends only on the corresponding `x` and not the other one.

The parallelness of the choice of is sometimes represented by stacking the paired quantifiers like this:

[image]

This quantfier cannot be expressed in first-order logic.

The parallel choices for the `y`'s are like prisoners being interrogated in separated rooms. They are each asked the respective questions `x1` or `x2` and must give respective answers `y1` and `y2` without knowing what the other one was asked, so they are liable to be trapped in inconsistent claims. The guards then evaluate the validity of their responses ointly by some function `f` that depends on both questions and answers. If the prisoners can always win this game, then `f` satisfied the Henkin quantifer `Q_H`.

Formally, the Henkin quantifier `Q_H` takes in a Boolean function `f` of four inputs `(x1,x2,y1,y2)`, and evaluates whether the following statement is True:

> For every `x1` there exists a `y1`, and for every `x2` there exists a `y2`, so that `f(x1,x2,y1,y2)` is `True`, and the choice of `y1` depends only on `x1` and the choice of `y2` depends only on `x2`.

Alternatively stated in [Skolem normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form)

> There exists functions `g1` and `g2` so that for every `x1` and `x2`, the function `f(x1,x2,g1(x1),g2(x2))` is `True`.

For this challenge, the domain of discourse will be natural numbers from `0` to `9`.

**Input:**

A function `f` that takes in four numbers `x1,x2,y1,y2`, each between `0` and `9` and produces a Boolean output.

**Output:**

A consistent Truthy value if `f` satisfies the Henkin quantifier `Q_H`, and a Falsey value if it does not.

---

**Questions for Sandbox:**

1. Does this challenge make any sense?
2. What should the input format be? Not every language can take in
   functions. What about nested lists? Subsets of four-digit numbers?

Comment: Let me see if I can interpret it. Does it mean that there exist two functions *g* and *h* such that *f(x1, x2, g(x1), h(x2))* is true for all *x1,x2*?

Comment: @feersum Yes, that's right.

Comment: The obvious input formats for non-functional languages would seem to be a 4D truth table array `boolean[][][][]` or a 2D "accepted" array `int[][4]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve a LaserTank level (optimally?) [WIP]

[LazerTank](http://perso.cgocable.ca/lasertank/ltank_en.html) is more than just a computer game, it is a blast from the past.  In this game, the player controls a tank that shoots lasers and navigates through a series of puzzles.  The goal of this challenge is to write a program that solve game levels.

TODO: Actually explain how LaserTank works.  There is an instructions page on the website.

Input will be an ASCII representation of the game map.  TODO: determine which characters stand for what stuff.

Output will be the list of actions required.  There are four possible actions for each step in the solution, "move forward," "turn left," "turn right," and "shoot".

Answer (score 0):

**Counting k-mers**

The task is to count the number of distinct substrings of length k, for k = 1,2,3,4,.....

**score**

Your score is the highest k you can get to on my computer in under 1 minute.

You should use http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/chromosomes/chr2.fa.gz as your input and ignore new lines.

You should ignore all newlines.  You can preprocess the input to decompress it before starting.

The following code outputs a histogram of all the 4-mers. You can then count how many there are with `wc`.

```
awk -v substr_length=4 '(len=length($0))>=substr_length{for (i=1; (i-substr_length)<len; i++) substrs[substr($0,i,substr_length)]++}; END{for (i in substrs) print substrs[i], i}' file.txt
```

(This question is not finished yet.)

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Comment: As pointed out by Geobits on chat, there's a simple approach which takes O(kn) to count distinct substrings of every length up to k.

Comment: @peter But can you do faster? It might be possible to optimise in the common cases. If every k-infix is unique, then you know the number of n-infixes for every n>k. A BWT might be a viable approach as well - not sure how long that would take.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was also thinking of adding a space restriction but I  haven't worked out those details yet.

Answer (score 0):

## Elevator Control [WIP]

The controller is still a WIP, but I have a decent idea of how it'll work.

You have been hired as a Vertical Integration Specialist (programmer) at Ascension Incorporated to write advanced elevator controller software. (backstory wip)

## Elevators are Cool

The current setup is that there will be ten floors and three elevators.  This is 100% subject to change. I'm not exactly sure how the game will be judged, below is an idea.

As people begin queue up, your elevators will be responsible for making sure that they get where they want to go.  Each game tick, there is a certain % chance that a person will queue up at a given floor with a random destination. You goal is to transport 1000 people in the least time possible.

## Details

Your submission will be the the form of a Java class.  This class must contain at least two methods: the constructor `mySubmission(Elevator[] elevators, Floor[] floors)` and `update(Elevator[] elevators, Floor[] floors)`.  The constructor class will be called once, and update after every game tick.

### Elevator Class:

- `int location` gives the current floor location of the elevator.  (Read-only)
- `int dest` gives the destination of the elevator.  All elevators have a destination, even an idle elevator, in which case the destination is the current floor. (readOnly)
- `String status` is `idle` or `busy`.  Elevators which are `idle` are not moving and have no floors in queue. (read-only)
- `boolean[] buttons` tells which buttons have been pushed, signifying that a person in the elevator wants to go to that floor.
- `ArrayList<Integer> destQueue` gives the list of destinations for this elevator.  An `idle` elevator with something in `destQueue` will become `busy` and have a new destination. (writable)
- `goToFloor(int i)` adds that floor to the queue if it is not already in it.
- `clearQueue()` clears the queue.  Simple as that.

### Floor Class

- `boolean waiting` means that somebody is at that floor.
- `boolean up` means that somebody on that floor wants to go up.
- `boolean down` means that somebody on that floor wants to do down.

Answer (score 0):

## Random distribution in array with exact number of occurences and max size

Write a program or a function, that takes 3 inputs `x y z`, where :

`x` is an integer representing the max size of each output array.
`y` is an integer representing the exact number of occurence of each `z` value.
`z` is a set of `n` integers to distribute

and outputs a set of arrays containing `z` values randomly distributed (each array must be unique, different ordered array are not the same).

## Rules

- Each value of `z` can only appear once in each output array
- `x` value is between `2` and `10`
- `y` value is between `1` and `10`
- `n` is between `2` and `50`
- `z`'s `n` values are between `0` and `50`
- If and only if `n * y` isn't divisible by `x` you can output one array with less than `x` elements
- "Random" means that every possible output must be produced with finite probability (barring the finite length of the PRNG's cycle)
- You can assume valid inputs, and there will always be at least 1 possible solution

## Example

Input :

```
4 5 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

Output :

```
[[3 18 16 10][9 0 2 11][6 12 0 9][15 16 10 4][4 17 16 14][14 3 15 2][5 4 7 16][17 5 0 13][13 11 7 6][2 9 8 12][5 13 7 2][7 1 8 14][11 19 17 0][17 19 6 13][3 1 5 15][15 18 0 7][19 14 18 10][1 16 10 9][1 12 14 10][9 15 4 12][8 4 3 5][19 11 18 3][13 12 17 11][6 1 8 19][18 8 2 6]]
```

Input

```
4 5 [0 1 2 3 4]
```

Output

```
[[0 3 2 1][0 3 2 4][3 2 1 4][2 0 1 3][1 0 3 4][4 2 0 1][4]]
```

## Winning Criterion

This is code-golf so the shortest answer wins.

## Note

This is actually based on SO question that I asked, and you can find a Java implementation here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544808/random-distribution-of-items-in-list-with-exact-number-of-occurences

## Sandbox

Definition of random : Should I accept output that contain same "subset" array ordered differently?
Output format : How can I better define the output expected?

Comment: I don't see why you posted this question here if you were to post it to main in an hour without any feedback.

Comment: What next question ? The last sandbox post was 9 hours ago. That one was just lucky that the right people were awake.

Comment: Is the choice of the word "set" deliberate? I.e. must all arrays in the output be unique?

Comment: As for randomness, if you want something decent you should specify that every possible output must be produced with finite probability (barring the finite length of the PRNG's cycle).

Comment: The rules seem to allow me to output a set of one-element arrays, reducing the problem to shuffling `y` copies of `z`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I updated my question with your suggestions. I also specified that differently ordered arrays are not considered the same.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can only output arrays of size different than `x` in the case `n * y` is not divisible by `x`

Comment: You should be aware that at some point (probably already) it will be shorter to just generate random outputs and then check for validity (and regenerate as long as it isn't).

Comment: @MartinBüttner You provided a 8 byte CJam implementation, I find that more than satisfying.

Comment: @Thrax That isn't valid by the updated rules, as it doesn't produce every possible output and doesn't ensure uniqueness of the arrays.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I could put those 2 (hard) rules as bonus, maybe?

Comment: @Thrax That's up to you. I think they change the challenge quite substantially, so I'm not sure if they are suitable for being a bonus, but I don't know.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Java implementation (non-golfed) is 1600 bytes. I don't find that particularily excessive. With an appropriate language, it should be reduced to no more than 300 I think.

Answer (score 0):

## Can you reach this chess position?

*This is currently a stub. If it makes sense I will write it out.*

You should write a program which given a chess position outputs a list of moves (white and black alternating) with which the given position can be reached from the standard starting position. Your goal is to minimize the number of moves.

### Input details:

will be in following the format (but of course not the staring position):

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

- Inputs will be chosen from random positions of random low-level games (~1200 Elo).
- You only have to reach the given position with legal moves. You don't have to care if any castling or en-passant was available in the input.
- You can choose whose turn it is.

### Output details:

- Is a list of `[a-f][1-8] [a-f][1-8][qrbn]?` (`[qrbn]?` is for promotion, if there is a standard notation for it, that will be used).

### Other details:

- Running time of your program should not take more than one minute on your computer.
- Program shouldn't be longer than 50Kb. *(this is against hardcoding databases thought that might wouldn't help **that much**)*
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.

### Scoring:

- Sum of the moves (half-moves) for the 20 provided inputs. If hardcoding happens those are subject to change. If a program can't reach a given input in 1 minute it's score is 300 for that testcase.

*Sandbox notes:*

*A validator would be useful. I can't do a JS snippet but maybe I can hack together a python3 one.*

*(You don't have to implement castling, en-passant, promotion if you don't want to and still can get a great entry.)*

Comment: One-minute limit? Is that for arbitrary positions? If so, beware that there are fiendish retrograde analysis problems that would stand up to search strategies.

Comment: @xnor You don't have to be able to solve 100% of the positions. If you can't solve one you receive 300 points for that one.

Comment: "one minute on **your** computer" seems to be a problem - giving an advantage to faster computers.

Comment: I'm contemplating a challenge which will require termination within 30 seconds on any computer, but that requires the code to measure its own runtime. The actually scoring will still all be done on my machine for fairness.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the Point of Maximum Light

Inspired by [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/light/6244031630934016) program, this challenge is about finding the point where the mouse should be placed, given an input in a form which will be specified later, in order to color the most pixels yellow.

The above link will bring you to a program with a hexagon, a triangle, and a line. When the mouse is moved over the shapes, light rays shine from the mouse and the various shapes absorb the light.

Input is given in this format: `[250,200,150,100 250,200,300,120 150,100,300,120] [250,350,350,250]` (Compare to the `lines` array in the aforementioned program). Your program is to assume the perimeter (`[0,0,400,0 0,0,0,400 400,0,400,400 0,400,400,400]`) is always present.

This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

**NOTE:** please tell me if I can clarify my question.

Comment: I would suggest you make the challenge self-contained... it's nice to have the link as a reference to the inspiration for your challenge, but people should be able to understand how exactly the program is supposed to work without having to follow the link.

Comment: on the link, where does one click in order to run the program?

Comment: When the link is clicked, you should see a (mostly) black 400 by 400 square on the right. Try mousing over the square.

Comment: Since this is inspired by a mouse pointer based game, I take it the output should be integer, even if half way between two pixels would give greater coverage?

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, the output should be an integer (or rather, two integers).

Comment: I assumed that would be the case, I was just asking so you could clarify the question by editing in a specific output format (or choice of formats).

Answer (score 0):

### Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

I'm not sure how or if this can even work in any language, but I figured I'd toss the idea up here for someone else to flesh out in case it's actually viable.

"[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)" is a grammatically correct American English sentence. This is possible because there are three different meanings of the word "buffalo" (or "Buffalo") used in the sentence, and some other words and punctuation are implied rather than explicitly included.

I think this would be a great code challenge to issue, if it is at all possible. It may not be proper for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but that would put an interesting spin on it as well.

The objective would be to create a script or program which is made up only of a single command, or sequence of commands, which is identically repeated throughout the source. No other code is permitted to fill or wrap the repeated piece. Within the script or program, those commands must do something in at least three different ways (or do three totally different somethings) despite being written exactly the same (perhaps with some allowance for deviations in capitalization, such as in the actual sentence) for every iteration.

A fictitious (and obviously invalid) PowerShell example is below.

Code:

```
echo 'buffalo';echo 'buffalo';echo 'buffalo';
```

Output

> buffalo
>   Buffalo
>   BUFFALO

(Note: The Output could be easily achieved by simply modifying the capitalization of "buffalo" within the script, but that would be in violation of the spirit of the challenge - such deviations, if permitted at all, should not be allowed in string literals.)

Comment: Have you heard of the language Ook?

Answer (score 0):

### Make a Space Heater

I've been out shoveling snow all day, and my hands are freezing! Heat them up with my  computer.

Here's an (ungolfed) Linux C solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main() {
    int cpu_cores = get_nprocs_conf();

    for (int i = 0; i < cpu_cores; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            nice(19);
            while (true);
        }
    }
    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Additional Rules:

1. It must use all my CPU cores! More cores means more heat. (Processes are not required. You can use threads, or whatever. Just keep my cores pegged.)
2. Don't slow down my system. I might want to watch cat videos while my hands are warming. (The example does this with [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice))
3. Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I see a few problems with this. For one, heating up the CPU cores too high may damage your computer. Second, different computers have different CPUs, so what heats up one may not heat up another.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Modern OSes will ease up on the CPU if it gets too hot. Also, every CPU you're likely to find in a consumer machine will get hot when it does a lot of work. Also, I may hay left this sitting here for a month. Oops. -- The idea with this challenge is to bring out languages that might not be perfectly optimized for golfing but are tightly integrated with the system. In practice, though, this would probably mean every answer would be in C, C++ or assembly.

Answer (score 0):

## One Code, All the Challenges

### This challenge has been ***abandoned*** due to poor wording. You may reclaim it if you wish without my permission.

### tag: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Now, I always want to solve as many [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)s as possible, so I thought "Why not solve them all at once?".

#### Your task

Create a block of code that solves another code-golf challenge on this Stack Exchange network. You must also make it so that when it is rotated (90°, 180° or 270°) it solves a *different* challenge on this website. Examples of rotated code-blocks:

```
0°       90°      180°     270°
AB       FCA      F G       EF 
CDE       DB      EDC      BD  
F G      GE        BA      ACG
```

The code golf that you are answering must have a shortest answer > 10 score (usually bytes). It may also not be a duplicate of another challenge.
Answers do not have to have a code-gold linked to every rotations, although this helps with score.

When rotating, take the shape that the code occupies, and rotate that. Some more examples:

```
0°       90°   | 0°      90°
print    p     | print   hsp
         r     | say~~   iar
         i     | hi by    yi
         n     |         b~n
         t     |         y~t
```

This means non-rectangular code is allowed, but whitespace (like-all other characters) *except* newlines must stay in-tact. This means the tildes (`~`) must be occupied with a character to allow for the rotate.

#### Scoring

`Number of bytes in code * ((number of rotations that solve a challenge) * -2 + 7)`
Lowest score wins.

```
Rotations | X   
        0 | Must work for at least one rotation
        1 | 5 
        2 | 3
        3 | 1
Number of bytes * X
```

**Note**
Please provide a link to each code golf question you are answering with each rotation. Also note that the questions answered *must* have been posted before this question, and each rotation must be in the same language. Also note if there are restrictions of source in one challenge, only the rotation that tries to solve that challenge has to comply with them.

#### Example:

> #### Python 3, 21 bytes, 2 rotations, 63 points
>
> 0 degrees: `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/print-hello-world`
>   180 degrees: `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3/crash-the-program`
>   (Don't put in links in `` ` ` `` in actual answers)
>
> ```
> print("Hello world!")
> ```
>
> 0 degrees: prints the string `'Hello world!'`
>   180 degrees: Crashes with a `SyntaxError` because of unopened close parenthesis.

Comment: @Bigtoes That was an error. Fixed it, Thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to say about non-rectangular code. Maybe if you had an example which actually contained non-rectangular code it would be clearer. And I think allowing people to solve any of the 3000 existing questions is too broad. It essentially makes the spec 3000 pages long.

Comment: Something tells me this question will just boil down to whoever can find the right subset of questions which work together. For example, taking the 1 byte from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13152/21487) sets the initial bar at 5.

Answer (score 0):

## Navigate My Time Machine

[challenge-type-undecided](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge-type-undecided)

This is a pretty broad idea, but time travel is a lot cooler than space travel.  The basic idea is that the program will have to sort out the path of various objects through time, given certain constraints as to what must be where, when.

There are a few different models of time machine that could be used, based upon which type of time travel we want to use.

One possible example is the time travel model used in the film Primer. Notably, the machine must be turned on before it can be used.  I find this model to be fairly "realistic," if that term can be used in regards to time travel.

[image]

There would also be the requirement of conservation of mass.  If there there are multiple copies of an object, then "the number of forward-moving copies" - "the number of backwards-moving copies" = 1.  The most important point is that there is a single "unified" timeline.

One idea is to create a long list of various objects, listing the known sightings of each one.  From this list of information, the program must sort out the path of each object through time, ensuring that each duplicate object is accounted for and that conservation of mass is obeyed.

Additional ideas include determining how much additional aging each object has experienced as a result of the time travel.

Answer (score 0):

## Game Of Riches

---

This is a programming challenge based off the game [AdVenture Capitalist](http://hyperhippo.ca/games/adventure-capitalist/).

### Goal Of The Game

---

The goal is to have the most angel investors after 1 month (2,592,000 seconds) of gameplay.

### Angel Investors

---

Angel Investors are the primary way to increase your profit in the long run. Angel Investors can be sacrificed for Angel Upgrades. Angel Investors also increase your profit by `ANGEL_EFFECTIVENESS`% each. For example, 20 angel investors increase your profit by 40%. You earn Angel Investors in proportion to the square root of your life earnings. The catch is that Angel Investors can only be used *after* a reset.

`ANGEL_EFFECTIVENESS` is `2` by default. It can be increased by unlocks and upgrades.

Angel Investors are earned according to this formula: `150 * sqrt(LIFETIME_EARNINGS / 1e15)`

### Money

---

You earn money through the use of businesses. Money is used to purchase businesses and upgrades. The more money you have earned in your lifetime (since your program started execution), the more angels flock to your cause.

### Businesses

---

Businesses can earn you money. There are 10 types of businesses. The price of a business increases exponentially. You can also earn unlocks by achieving certain numbers of businesses. You start with 1 lemonade stand.

```
Name               |    Base Price   |  Base Profit / second  | Price Increase per Purchase
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LEMONADE_STAND     |              $4 |                  $1.66 | 7%
NEWSPAPER_DELIVERY |             $60 |                    $20 | 15%
CAR_WASH           |            $720 |                    $90 | 14%
PIZZA_DELIVERY     |          $8,640 |                   $360 | 13%
DONUT_SHOP         |        $103,680 |                 $2,160 | 12%
SHRIMP_BOAT        |      $1,244,160 |                 $6,480 | 11%
HOCKEY_TEAM        |     $14,929,920 |                $19,440 | 10%
MOVIE_STUDIO       |    $179,159,040 |                $58,320 | 9%
BANK               |  $2,149,908,480 |               $174,960 | 8%
OIL_COMPANY        | $25,798,901,760 |               $804,816 | 7%
```

### Unlocks

---

Unlocks are bonuses that are earned when a set goal has been achieved.

Example list (not actual):

```
LEMONADE_STAND;25;LEMONADE_STAND;PROFIT;2
NEWSPAPER_STAND;900;OIL_COMPANY;PROFIT;11
ALL;2222;ALL;PROFIT;2
```

### Upgrades

---

Upgrades are bonuses that are purchased with money or angels. See Angel Upgrades for details on upgrades that are purchased with angels.

Example list (not actual):

```
0;CASH;2.5e5;LEMONADE_STAND;PROFIT;3
1;CASH;500000;NEWSPAPER_DELIVERY;PROFIT;3
2;CASH;1e21;ANGEL;EFFECTIVENESS;1
```

### Angel Upgrades

---

Angel Upgrades are bonuses that are purchased with the sacrifice of angels. Angels sacrificed for this purpose are **not** regained on reset of a game.

Example list (not actual):

```
3;ANGEL;10000;ALL;PROFIT;3
4;ANGEL;1e32;CAR_WASH;COUNT;100
5;ANGEL;3.4e134;ANGEL;EFFECTIVENESS;10
```

### Resetting

---

When you reset your game, you lose all unlocks, upgrades, businesses, and money that you had. You start out with 1 lemonade stand all over again. So why would you want to do that? Because all angels that you may have earned last session are now activated. The angels that you didn't spend last session are also carried over. With these angels, you can earn larger profits faster than those earned in last session.

Lifetime earnings are ***not*** reset when you reset.

The angels gained with reset is `150 * sqrt(LIFETIME_EARNINGS / 1e15) - ANGELS - ANGELS_SACRIFICED`

## Bot Details

---

Your bot will be an independent program that sends and receives input and output through stdout, and stdin. They are allowed to write to and create files in the directory that they are in. All files that they create must be destroyed on death of the program. The program must be deterministic. If the program does not finish the game within 5 minutes, it is disqualified.

Your bot can send through stdout requests for information. Here is a list of each request along with the reply:

```
Request                                                                                    Reply
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIME                                                                        game time in seconds
TIME_LEFT                                                              game time left in seconds
MONEY                                                                               cash on hand
LIFETIME_EARNINGS                                                              lifetime earnings
ANGELS                                                                             active angels
ANGELS_SACRIFICED                                       number of angels sacrificed in life-time
ANGELS_GAIN                                   number of angels that would be gained with a reset
COUNT type†                                                                       number of type
COST type†                                                                     cost of next type
PROFIT type†                                                               profit of all of type
UPGRADE or CASH_UPGRADE                                     the next cash upgrade you can afford
ANGEL_UPGRADE                                              the next angel upgrade you can afford
UPGRADES                                              the newline separated list of all upgrades
CASH_UPGRADES                                    the newline separated list of all cash upgrades
ANGEL_UPGRADES                                  the newline separated list of all angel upgrades
UPGRADE id                                                         the description of an upgrade
NEXT_UNLOCK type†                                                 the next unlock with type type
UNLOCKS                                                the newline separated list of all unlocks
UNLOCKS type†                           the newline separated list of all unlocks with type type
UNLOCK id                                                           the description of an unlock
```

<sub>† One of `LEMONADE_STAND`,`NEWSPAPER_DELIVERY`, `CAR_WASH`, `PIZZA_DELIVERY`, `DONUT_SHOP`, `SHRIMP_BOAT`, `MOVIE_STUDIO`, `BANK`, `OIL_COMPANY`, `ALL`</sub>

**These commands return no value:**

```
Request                                                                                                  Action
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WAIT seconds                                                                              warps forward in time
WAIT_MONEY x                                                                     waits until you have x dollars
WAIT_ANGEL x                                                                      waits until you have x angels
BUY type amount                 purchases items one at a time, waiting as needed until you can afford each item
RESET                                                                                        resets the session
BUY_UPGRADE id                                                                             purchases an upgrade
If you can't afford the upgrade it will wait until you can afford it if it is a CASH upgrade or will return 
immediately if it is an ANGEL upgrade
```

Format of an upgrade string: `id;purchased[5];typeOfUpgrade[1];cost;bonus_string`
Format of an unlock string: `id;achieved[5];typeOfUnlock[2];amountNeeded;bonus_string`
Format of a bonus string: `type[3];subtype[4];amount`

If subtype is `PROFIT` or `COST`, the bonus is applied multiplicatively, otherwise the bonus is applied additively.

<sub>[1]: One of `CASH`, `ANGEL`

[2]: One of `LEMONADE_STAND`,`NEWSPAPER_DELIVERY`, `CAR_WASH`, `PIZZA_DELIVERY`, `DONUT_SHOP`, `SHRIMP_BOAT`, `MOVIE_STUDIO`, `BANK`, `OIL_COMPANY`, `ALL`

[3]: One of `ANGEL`, `LEMONADE_STAND`,`NEWSPAPER_DELIVERY`, `CAR_WASH`, `PIZZA_DELIVERY`, `DONUT_SHOP`, `SHRIMP_BOAT`, `MOVIE_STUDIO`, `BANK`, `OIL_COMPANY`, `ALL`

[4]: `EFFECTIVENESS` if type is `ANGEL`; otherwise one of `COUNT`, `PROFIT`, `COST`

[5]: One of `true` or `false`</sub>

### Controller:

TODO

### Score:

Your score is determined as `log10(ANGEL_TOTAL)`. The person with the largest score wins the contest.

`ANGEL_TOTAL` is determined by adding all active angels, sacrificed angels, and the number of angels you would gain with a reset.

### Leaderboard:

N/A

tag: `code-challenge`

Comment: This is a very long post and only about 25% complete. It would really benefit from reformatting to take less space. Why not represent the companies in a table, and have parameterised commands to get the number, cost, and profits of company type X?

Comment: Is the number of angels gained by a reset `150 * sqrt(lifeTimeEarnings / 1e15)` or `150 * sqrt(lifeTimeEarnings / 1e15) - ANGELS - ANGELS_SACRIFICED`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's the latter :)

Answer (score 0):

## Design Logic Circuits with CSWAP Gates

A **universal logic gate** is a logic gate is one that is capable of creating any other logic gate or circuit.  For example, it is possible to wire together dozens of NAND gates to form any logic circuit you so desire.

Beyond a universal gate, a **reversible logic gate** is one whose (multiple) outputs can be used to determine the input.  One notable reversible universal gate is the [Fredkin Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate), also known as the CSWAP gate.  This gate has three inputs and three outputs, yet is very simple.  CSWAP stands for "controlled swap" and describes exactly what the gate does.  If the first input is a `0`, the three outputs are the same as the three inputs.  If the first input is a `1`, the second and third outputs are swapped.

Here is the ever-so-important truth table.

```
in  | out
----+----
000 | 000
001 | 001
010 | 010
011 | 011
100 | 100
101 | 110
110 | 101
111 | 111
```

### The Challenge

You goal is to write a program that takes a truth table as input and constructs a logic circuit to match it. (other ideas are taking a non-CSWAP circuit as input and converting it to CSWAP).

Here are the rules of circuit design:

- A circuit has a certain number of inputs and outputs, the quantities of which will be given.
- You have an unlimited supply of CWAP gates with which to construct circuits.
- You also have an unlimited supply of constants (a source that always takes on the assigned value) and trash bins (a place to send an unneeded bit).
- Each data source (circuit input / gate output / constant) must be linked via wire to exactly one data sink (circuit output / gate input / trash bin), and vice-versa.
- Possible extra rule: no loops in the circuit.

### ASCII representation

Using ASCII to draw the circuits may be unnecessary, but here is how it could be done.

- Wires are `-` and `|`, which connect the two horizontally or vertically adjacent cells.
- Inputs are capital letters, while outputs are lowercase letters.  Constants are 1s and 0s.  Trash bins are `#`.
- CSWAP gates are formed by `OXX` in any of the four basic orientations. The `O` is the control, while `XX` are the two inputs/outputs to be swapped.  I might need to adjust this so that adjacent gates with multiple orientations are unambiguous.

**AND gate**

```
A-O-#
B-X-#
0-X-a
```

**NOT gate**

```
A-O-#
0-X-#
1-X-a
```

(more details coming sometime not now)

Answer (score 0):

### **Children Sum Game**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

When I was a kid I liked to play a sum game with my cousin (I don't know if there's a name for the game).

The first player choose a number between 1 to 9, then by turns players go summing a number between 1 to 9 to the result until one is able to reach 100.

So, the challenge consist in create a program to play this game. The program has to choose randomly if the human or the computer starts the game. The player should input the sum of a number between 1 to 9 and the previous result and the program should check if the sum is correct. Then the program should sum another number between 1 to 9 and give the result. Finally it should display a message.

Here's a example of the game, suppose computer starts:

```
Computer: 5
Player: 12
Computer: 18
Player: 25
Computer: 30
Player: 39
Computer: 42
Player: 55
Computer: Incorrect sum!
Player: 48
Computer: 57
Player: 65
Computer: 73
Player: 82
Computer: 90
Player: 92
Computer: 100
You lose!
```

Ideally, the program should have a strategy to make it difficult (for a kid) to win the game.

Outputs should be: `You win!`, `You lose!` and `Incorrect sum!`

Comment: This is equivalent to the [subtraction game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#The_subtraction_game_S.281.2C2.2C....2Ck.29), a variant of Nim.

Comment: The correct spelling is actually "You lose", not "You loose".

Comment: @ProgramFOX sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Zgarb is [The 100 game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#The_100_game), but I used to play with numbers between 1 to 9.

Comment: "Ideally, the program should have a strategy to make it difficult (for a kid) to win the game." This part seems very vague and subjective. How difficult is difficult enough? Essentially, if the player starts the computer can always beat him. But that means it's not difficult, but impossible for the player to win. Likewise, if the computer starts he has no way of making it difficult for the player, because the player can always win.

Comment: @MartinBüttner If the computer always starts and the kid playing is learning how to sum, maybe it would be interesting to see when the kid get the strategy to win the game.

Comment: @Migue That is not what your spec asks for though.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I know. I was just thinking how to change the question to make it some way interesting.

Answer (score 0):

## Help the President!

### Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There is an anonymous president of a country who needs your help! He wants to retain absolute control, but needs to have elections to prevent uprisings. They ask you to create a program to help them [gerrymander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering).

These are the specifications:

#### Input

(You will receive input via stdin or as a function argument)

You will be given an array of arrays of strings to represent the locations of voters (a 2D matrix), i.e:

```
[["Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic"],
 ["Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic"],
 ["Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican"],
 ["Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican"]]
```

Which is

```
[["Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic"], ["Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic"], ["Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican"], ["Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican"]]
```

You will also receive a party that is meant to win, like `"Democratic"` or `"Republican"`. These will be in the matrix.

Thirdly, you will receive district sizes. The amount of items in the matrix will be a multiple of this. All districts must be this size.

### Output

An array of arrays of coordinates. Either the top left or the bottom left may be `[0, 0]` or `[1, 1]`. Going right increases the second number and going down / up increases / decreases the first number.

This country uses a [first-past-the-post voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting) (Most votes win) per district (except if there is a tie, none of them win). You must split the matrix of voters into districts in such a way that the party wins as many districts as possible. A district is given by one of the arrays in the output. Districts must be contiguous, and going diagonally is *not* contiguous. Some visualisations by [this helpful CGP Grey video on Gerrymandering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mky11UJb9AY) and one example outputs:

```
f([["D", "R", "D"], ["D", "D", "R"], ["D", "D", "R"]], "D", 3)
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]
# In this case, the D party wins all of the votes.
f([["D", "R", "D"], ["D", "D", "R"], ["D", "D", "R"]], "R", 3)
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]
# R wins a third of the seats
```

```
This demographic could be visualised as

D  R  D
D  D  R
D  D  R
```

(Note there may be many possible "best" district boundaries. In this case, return any of them. And in a case where there are two cases that give the party the same amount in both cases, but the second case gives a smaller majority to another party, return the latter)

```
f([["B", "R", "B", "R", "B"], ["G", "B", "G", "R", "Y"], ["G", "R", "Y", "B", "Y"], ["B", "G", "B", "G", "Y"]], 4, "Y")
[[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]], [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3]], [[2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2]], [[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 3], [3, 4]]]
# In this election, Y wins 2, B wins 1 and 2 are undecided
```

### Sandbox notes

This seems way too wordy for a problem which seems so simple. Any areas where it could be clarified to be more concise? I think it's my organisation of stuff that makes it unclear.

Comment: Your proposal seems very similar to [this earlier one](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4894/32014). Is that intentional? Also, you should state whether the districts must have the same size.

Comment: @Zgarb I never actually saw that. This one can be easier / harder than that one, as my one asks for _the_ best district maps, but does not restrict perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

## Cooperative Tamagotchi

This is a new twist to the Tamagotchi-style ideas floating around.  I also plan on creating a "no rules" version, but the cooperative version is the more  complete idea at the moment.

---

Tamagotchi, more popularly known as StackEgg, is a game in which you nurture the growth of an adorable pet, also more popularly known as PPCG.  The pet has a set of statistics which reflect the health and well-being of the pet.  You also have a series of buttons.  When you press a button, the pet's stats are affected.  One stat receives a boost, but the other stats that did not receive a boost slowly wither away.

In the game, your goal is to work together to win a game of Tamagotchi. Each contestant program casts votes to determine which move will be played in a given game cycle. This is a competition, however, because your personal contributions are being measured. If you vote for a move, and that move wins the election, then the effect of the move will affect your score.  If the action was beneficial to your pet, you gain points.  If the action was detrimental to your pet, you will lose points.

---

I don't have a "theme" for the Tamagotchi yet.  Here are some ideas for how it would work.  I could alternatively wait for the source for StackEgg to be released or reverse-engineered and use those more realistic rules.

There would probably be a single game phase, probably based on the "full site" phase of StackEgg in terms of functionality.  This means that there are five stacks and five "constructive" buttons.

Each stat has two numbers: the number of hearts, which is visible, and a decay counter, which is hidden.  When calculating a player's positive or negative contribution, only the number of hearts is used (?).

More details coming sometime not now.

Comment: One of the key (fun) things that StackEgg had going for it was *figuring out* what exactly did what. With the controller source being open (I assume), that mystery is gone. Without some big tweaks, I fear there will only be one optimum vote pattern which everyone uses.

Comment: @Bigtoes Yeah, I'm thinking about that too.  Do you think adding in randomness would help?

Comment: @PhiNotPi only if the randomness is at the initialization of the system, not each turn, so the bots have to figure out the best strategy, maybe?

Comment: How about completely randomly initializing the effects of each button, such as which stats are helped and hurt, and by how much?  There would have to be some way to determine which settings are playable, but bots would have fun time trying to figure out causes and effects.

Comment: @PhiNotPi I like the idea of randomly initializing the buttons. Also, perhaps a better way to measure the fitness of the bots would be to run the game `K*N` times, where `N` is the number of bots and `K` is a large constant, with a different bot missing for each of the `N` batches of `K` games. The score of a bot would be the average score of the games in which it participates.

Answer (score 0):

## Quine Creator

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The program `F` is in language `A`. `F` takes a program in language `B` as input. Lets call this program `G`. `F` outputs a program in language `B`. Lets call this program `O`. `O` Takes some input and for some values it will be a quine and for others it will run `G`.

The exact values which `O` decides behaviour must be the same for each different input to `F` but you can decide what the conditions will be. They must be short (5 or less bytes), reasonable and not turned into code and executed for the sake of a shorter program `F`. Acceptable behaviours include (but are not limited to):

- Quines for even digit, `G` for odd
- Quines for truthy input, `G` for anything else
- Quines for the input "0", `G` for anything else

For example your program `F` could be written in Java and take a Python program (`G`) as input and output a program in Python (`O`) that runs `G` when given at least 1 arg and prints it's source when not given any args.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing

Comment: This is *very* similar to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41375/8478). I'd definitely be tempted to close this as a duplicate. You're also missing a winning criterion.

Comment: The code challenge tag is for when you make up your own winning criterion, so it would contradict the code golf tag. You might want to include a short sentence like "This is code golf, so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins." anyway, although the tag is pretty clear. Just for completeness's sake.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That challenge is different to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41375/8478) but I'm new to asking questions, so you be the judge of if mine should go ahead.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly different, but very similar I think. For the record, my CJam submission would be ``"{q{;"q'}"_~"`"?}_~"`` which may look quite different but is essentially the same idea. I guess I probably wouldn't vote to close as duplicate myself, because I've got a dupehammer on the code golf tag, but I'm just saying others might think it's a dupe and close it. (Just to be clear, this is not a bad challenge idea. I really quite like it... just saying something very similar has been done before.)

Comment: One thing that's not entirely clear about the challenge is how general `G` is allowed to be. E.g. if `O` reads all of STDIN to decide whether to use `G` or print `O`, then `G` cannot receive any input on STDIN. Is this fine?

Comment: Is your edit intended to address my comment? If so, let me try to rephrase my question. I was asking whether `G` must potentially be completely general. E.g. the program `G` could be a program which reads a string on STDIN and reverses it. But if I generate `O` such that it reads all of STDIN and is a quine if STDIN is empty and calls `G` otherwise... then `O` has already read all of STDIN and `G` will have nothing to read on STDIN to reverse. Would this be allowed or does `G` have to be completely general?

Comment: In other words can the input method of `O` be destructive? Another example would be clearing the `ARGV` array to determine which code to execute - if I did this, then `G` could never use `ARGV` itself.

Comment: @MartinBüttner you can try to rephrase the question if you like. `O` should not consume too much input and I also think that `G` should be able to receive any input possible. So `O` taking the first arg and giving the rest to `G` or taking the first 4 bytes of `STDIN` would be fine. And yes the edit was sort of made in response to you comment so feel free to make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

### Find sequences in [RSA_1024](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-1024)

I found an interesting way to factor numbers, while its far from been any efficient in compare to [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) known methods, its lots of fun!

Lets assume we want to factor `N`. `X` will be its factor, if and only if

```
N/X = floor(N/X)
```

So theoretically, if you could find a different representation of `floor(N/X)`, you could easily find `X`, so while find such representation is unlikely it is very easy to find it within a small range, for example take a look at `floor(N/X)` of `N = 691 ∗ 983 = 679253`

At left is `X` at right is `floor(N/X) - floor(N/(X+1))`

```
512 2 
513 3 
514 3 
515 2 
516 3 
517 2 
518 3 
519 2 
520 3 
521 2 
522 3 
523 2 
524 3 
525 2 
526 3 
527 2 
528 2 
529 3 
530 2 
531 3 
532 2 
533 2 
534 3 
535 2 
536 3 
537 2 
538 2 
539 3 
540 2 
541 2 
542 3 
543 2 
544 2 
545 2 
546 3 
547 2 
548 2 
549 2 
550 3 
551 2 
552 2 
553 2 
554 3 
555 2 
556 2 
557 2 
558 2 
559 3 
560 2 
561 2 
562 2 
563 2 
564 2 
565 2 
566 3 
567 2 
568 2 
569 2 
570 2 
571 2 
572 2 
573 2 
574 2 
575 2 
576 2 
577 2 
578 2 
579 2 
580 2 
581 2 
582 2 
583 2 
584 2 
585 2 
586 2 
587 2 
588 2 
589 2 
590 2 
591 2 
592 2 
593 2 
594 2 
595 2 
596 2 
597 2 
598 2 
599 1 
600 2 
601 2 
602 2 
603 2 
604 2 
605 2 
606 1 
607 2 
608 2 
609 2 
610 2 
611 2 
612 1 
613 2 
614 2 
615 2 
616 2 
617 1 
618 2 
619 2 
620 2 
621 1 
622 2 
623 2 
624 2 
625 1 
626 2 
627 2 
628 2 
629 1 
630 2 
631 2 
632 1 
633 2 
634 2 
635 1 
636 2 
637 2 
638 2 
639 1 
640 2 
641 1 
642 2 
643 2 
644 1 
645 2 
646 2 
647 1 
648 2 
649 1 
650 2 
651 2 
652 1 
653 2 
654 1 
655 2 
656 2 
657 1 
658 2 
659 1 
660 2 
661 1 
662 2 
663 2 
664 1 
665 2 
666 1 
667 2 
668 1 
669 2 
670 1 
671 2 
672 1 
673 2 
674 1 
675 2 
676 1 
677 2 
678 1 
679 2 
680 1 
681 2 
682 1 
683 1 
684 2 
685 1 
686 2 
687 1 
688 2 
689 1 
690 1 
691 2 
692 1 
693 2 
694 1 
695 2 
696 1 
697 1 
698 2 
699 1 
700 2 
701 1 
702 1 
703 2 
704 1 
705 1 
706 2 
707 1 
708 1 
709 2 
710 1 
711 1 
712 2 
713 1 
714 1 
715 2 
716 1 
717 1 
718 2 
719 1 
720 1 
721 2 
722 1 
723 1 
724 2 
725 1 
726 1 
727 1 
728 2 
729 1 
730 1 
731 2 
732 1 
733 1 
734 1 
735 2 
736 1 
737 1 
738 1 
739 2 
740 1 
741 1 
742 1 
743 2 
744 1 
745 1 
746 1 
747 1 
748 2 
749 1 
750 1 
751 1 
752 1 
753 2 
754 1 
755 1 
756 1 
757 1 
758 2 
759 1 
760 1 
761 1 
762 1 
763 1 
764 2 
765 1 
766 1 
767 1 
768 1 
769 1 
770 1 
771 2 
772 1 
773 1 
774 1 
775 1 
776 1 
777 1 
778 2 
779 1 
780 1 
781 1 
782 1 
783 1 
784 1 
785 1 
786 1 
787 2 
788 1 
789 1 
790 1 
791 1 
792 1 
793 1 
794 1 
795 1 
796 1 
797 1 
798 1 
799 1 
800 1 
801 2 
802 1 
803 1 
804 1 
805 1    
806 1 
807 1 
808 1 
809 1 
810 1 
811 1 
812 1 
813 1 
814 1 
815 1 
816 1 
817 1 
818 1 
819 1 
820 1 
821 1 
822 1 
823 1
```

Its easy to tell that in the range of 566,599 `floor(N/X)` act like a strait line `y = 2x + 566`. Also it's easy to verify as we can calculate the difference between `floor(N/566)` and `floor(N/599)` and see if its equal to `2 * 599 - 566`, and indeed it is.

So now lets play

### Input

Your input is the number [RSA_1024](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-1024), while we will only use this input, your app should be able to work with any other inputs as well.

### Output

10,000 sequences that you found starting from Sqr([RSA_1024](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-1024)) and going up. Each sequences will be outputted in a new line. For each sequences you should output the next

- starting range value
- end range value
- type

Type is just a string defined by you that tells us what kind of sequence is it, strait-line or some thing else.

After you output the sequences, output one line with the total range you been able to cover with all the sequences.

### Criteria

Who covers the biggest Range wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Realistic Fractal Terrain Generation

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Don't you find that typical algorithms to generate random fractal terrains are boring and not too much realistic?

Fractal terrain generation is usually implemented with some random noise function applied in a fractal way. This can be seen with the typical Diamond-Square algorithm or the Perlin Noise function:

Diamond-Squares example output:

[image: Diamond-Squares example output]

Perlin noise example output:

[image: Perlin noise example output]

The problem is that these are used by their simplicity in creating them, but they are actually pretty boring when they are used as height maps:

[image: Diamond-Squares as heigh-map]

[image: Perlin noise as heigh-map]

*... To be continued ...*

Comment: Terrain generation is interesting.  I'd like to see this idea developed.  Here is a simple, but pretty good, terrain generator, if you are looking for examples: [Realistic Terrain Generation in 130 Lines](http://www.playfuljs.com/realistic-terrain-in-130-lines/).

Answer (score 0):

## Make a fighter, then have them battle

Well, I was browsing around KOTH one day. I found two little interesting challenges: [Save the last bullet for yourself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34833/save-the-last-bullet-for-yourself) and [Codémon, I choose you!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45285/cod%C3%A9mon-i-choose-you). But what if we combined the two?

#### How your bot will work

Each match, your bot is assigned an opponent. It is randomly decided who goes first. Your bot is given HP of 100. You must output:
`ATKID DEFID MOVED ATKDIR DEFDIR`
`ATKID` is the attack's ID, and `DEFID` is the defense (or support) ID, for skills. MOVED is your move direction, on a number-pad (5 being 'stay still'). ATKDIR and DEFDIR are attack and defense skill directions (for Bullet, Wall, etc.)
Your bot must accept the following as input:
`MYHP YOURHP MYPOS YOURPOS (additional projectile positions)`

Your bot is allowed 2 attack and 2 defense skills.
List of attack skills:

> 0: Attack: Deal 10 damage.
> 1: Psychic Blast: Deal 5 damage this turn and 5 damage the next.
> 2: Bullet: Fire off a bullet that damages for 15 points when it hits an enemy.
> 3: Hadouken: Fire of a large flaming ball that can fly for 3 squares, and deals 50 damage.

List of defense skills:

> 0: Block: Block up to 10 points of damage this turn.
> 1: Heal: Heal for 10 points.
> 2: Wall: Add a wall in target direction.

#### How the arena works

The arena starts as follows:

```
==========
|        |
|        | 
|a      b|
|        |
|        |
==========
```

where a and b are bots' starting positions.

### Meta Questions

- What should I add as skills? Healing? Defensive?
- Is the arena too small?
- Have I left out any restrictions?
- Can I have some help with the 2D grid?
- Is the input/output sufficient?
- Does anyone want to pick up this challenge? I already have another KOTH, this was just an idea everyone liked.

Answer (score 0):

## Missing distance between points

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [error-correction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction) [and-some-other-tags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/and-some-other-tags)

There are `N` points on a straight line. Someone calculates all possible distances between each pair of points and sort them.

In the following example I used 5 points. The sorted list of distances is `[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17, 20, 22]`.

```
---X--X------X---------X-----X---

   |-2|---6--|----9----|--5--|
   |-----8---|-------14------|
      |--------15------|
   |---------17--------|
      |----------20----------|
   |----------22-------------|
```

You will receive the list, but one of the numbers is unreadable. This will be indicated by a zero. So you might receive the list `[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 15, 17, 20, 22]`. Your job is to find the missing number.

### Input / Output:

Write a function/program that finds the missing number. The input (via STDIN, command-line argument, prompt or function argument) format is a list or an array of distances (integers). You can optionally take the number of points (one integer) as a second parameter if you want. The output (via return value or STDOUT) is one single integer, namely the missing number in the distances list.

This is code-golf. Therefore the shortest code wins.

### Test cases:

```
#points, distances -> output
5, [2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 15, 17, 20, 22] -> 14
3, [1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4] -> 2
...
```

### Sandbox notes:

- This challenge is based on one problem of this year's Mathematical Kangaroo. My dad is a math teacher and brought me a copy of the 7.-8. grades test.
- Example and test cases don't look pretty and will be improved and extended for the final question on PPCG.
- My main concern about the challenge is the speed of the programs. My first (and only) solution is quite slow, because of the bad time complexity (about `(n^2)^(n-1)`, where `n` is the number of points on the line). The 5-point example takes already about 1 second to compute, a 6-point example took about 10 minutes. My guess is, that most code-golf solutions will use a similar approach and the programs may be quite difficult to test.

  There's definitely a better way of computing the missing number.

  Maybe I'll add a few big testcases (one with 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 points) and promise a 50% bonus if the program can solve all test-cases in under one minute.

Comment: Are you sure the solution is unique?

Answer (score 0):

## Shadows to Height Maps

The goal of this code challenge will be to take a grayscale image with shading as input and produce a height-map image with the same dimensions as output.

The input image will be a grayscale 256x256 png image, shaded with only a diffuse term, no ambient or specular term. It will be lit by a directional light source hitting the surface at a 45 degree angle, from above.

The output must be a 256x256 png image containing the height-map.

This is a code-challenge, the answer with the most accurate results wins. (A perfect match between the reverse engineered height-map and the original height-map used to produce the shaded image is near impossible, it is not expected that they are identical).

(working on test cases)

tags:

image-processing, code-challenge, graphical-output, conversion

Answer (score 0):

## SVG file optimization

Yep, I got my idea off of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50837/can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-an-svg-to-be-closer-to-its-jpeg-equivalent), and it's amazing answer. All credit for this question goes to [Illmari Karonen's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/50857)

Now, for the challenge: Write a program that removes unnecessary clutter from SVG files in order to reduce their byte counts.

1. Remove comments `<!-- comment -->`
2. remove metadata `<metadata ...>` `</metadata>`
3. Shorten necessary ids to 1 letter, and remove unused ids.
4. remove unnecessary attributes and XML namespace attributes

Any other methods used to shorten the SVG files are welcome. (You can refer to the linked answer to look at an extensive list of ways to shorten SVG files)

Your program's score is how many bytes it removes from these SVG files:

test cases in progress

Comment: See also [Warm Welcome Secret Hat](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42389/194). If you're going to allow changing the paths, you should specify permitted changes / accuracy. E.g. if a transform is given to 3d.p. and the path coordinates to 3d.p., inlining the transform and then rounding to 3d.p. could produce visually perceptible changes.

Answer (score 0):

## Minimal convex partition (code-golf)

The goal of this challenge is dividing up the 'white' shape of a given 'black and white' pixel image into smaller pieces, which together form the original image (let's call this *a partition*). The restriction is that those pieces have to be *convex*, in our case everything is made up from square pixels, therefore the convex pieces can only be rectangles.
Now of course you can just divide the whole shape up into the pixels it consists of, but that way you will get too many pieces (usually). The goal here is finding one partition that has the lowest number of (convex) pieces.

### Specs

#### Input

The 'black and white' pixel image of $n \times m$ pixels is given as a string, row by row, each row separated by a comma. The *white* pixels are represented by a full stop `.`, and the *black* pixels are represented by a hash mark `#`.

#### Output

The output consists of the same string, but now the white pixels must be replaced by alphabetic characters, one character for each piece of the partition. The minimal number of partition never exceeds 26 (you do not have to consider input that does not meed this condition), therefore you only have to use the letters `a-z`. If the minimal number is $n$, you have to use the first $n$ letters of the alphabet. Of course, the output is not necessarily unique.

Examples (without the commas, for better visibility):

```
n=2:
Input: 
#.
..
Ouptut:
#A
BB

n=4
Input:
....
..#.
....
Output:
AABB
AA#C
DDDD

n=6
Input:
.....
.#...
.....
...#.
.....
```

## META:

I'd be happy for any interesting input examples. I could not think of any really interesting ones right away now.

Comment: Very similar: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44654/14215 The output might not be *minimal* in some cases, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I did not remember this challenge but it is indeed similar, but I still think looking for the solution with the minimal numbers of rectangles is again a different challenge, don't you agree? But I just noticed that I could write the introduction way more intuitive by using *covering a region with rectangles* instead of *partitioning into convex pieces*=)

Answer (score 0):

## Randomly generated "Bézier petals"

### Introduction

A "bézier petal" is a:

- [simple closed curve](http://www.mathwords.com/s/simple_closed_curve.htm) (no loops or self-intersection)
- made by two cubic Bézier curves which

  - share endpoints
  - but not necessarily control points

### Challenge

The challenge is to **generate these randomly**, such that:

- the entire space of possible valid curves is covered,
- any specific valid curve is as likely as any other,
- no "degenerate" (non-simple) petals are output.

### Background

I've been thinking about this for a while (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJdApKcAVD0), but was only able to arrive at a [partial solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20321/how-can-i-tell-when-two-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-intersect), which only covers a "safe" subset of possibilities (it never generates crescent or s-shapes). But, having followed this site for a while, I know that many of you are *way* more clever than I am.

### Output

The result should be a function which returns a single random petal, defined by two endpoints and two sets of two control points (six values in all) on a Cartesian plane — let's say with values between -1 and 1.

### Notes

Ideally, the algorithm works in constant time, or at least has a bounded stop; generating and filtering out degenerate petals until a good one is found is acceptable but a step down.

Entries which do not cover the entire possible space but do so with low complexity and at least beat out my "sort radially around center" [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20321/how-can-i-tell-when-two-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-intersect) are partial credit.

### Sandbox notes

*I'll add some illustrations for valid and invalid petals, once I draw them.*

Comment: Are you sure "any specific valid curve is as likely as any other" is well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

**IRC reader**

Internet Relay Chat (or IRC for short) is a simple yet popular chat communication method. The challenge is to create a program that can take an IRC server from program arguments and print out new messages sent on that server.

e.g.: `<your_irc_client> irc.freenode.net`

A very simple implementation in Python of this idea which does not print responses to the user can be found [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/1968)

Answer (score 0):

## Interpret a Turing-Complete Language

*This challenge is inspired by [this esolangs.org page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golf), which lists some languages with very small interpreters.  There have been some similar challenges before, like [this one about a self-interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/585/self-interpreting-interpreter), or a few other interpreter challenges, like one for [BF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck?s=1|1.4268).*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

This goal of this challenge is to write the smallest interpreter possible for a Turing-complete language.  You may choose *any* Turing complete language (even one you create?) to interpret.

Your interpreter should take input representing the program to be executed, and give output representing the end result of the program.  "Interactive" I/O is not required.

### More Rules

Your interpreter program may not contain/execute any `eval`-like commands.

Comment: Maybe this could be a popularity contest, and whoever has the most creative answer wins?

Comment: I like this, but I think it needs to be more specific.  Why not pick a specific [OISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer#Instruction_types)? That would probably be the winning strategy for the more general problem anyway. Also, I/O format should either be locked down or explicitly left open. If I'm golfing an OISC in Python 2, for example, I'd like to have the I/O be the memory of the machine represented as a Python list, read via `input()`. Is that okay, or cheating?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI For the popularity-contest version, see [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/create-a-programming-language-interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

## Number of ways to sum [1..n] with [n+1..2n] such that each sum is prime

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

In as few bytes as possible, write a program or function which produces this sequence ([A070897](https://oeis.org/A070897)), either as an infinite list on STDOUT, or in your interpreter of choice.

### Example

`a(5)=2` because there are two ways: `1+10,2+9,3+8,4+7,5+6` and `1+6,2+9,3+10,4+7,5+8`

### Rules

No built-in primality tests. No lookup table ;). No standard loopholes.

Comment: Are build-in prime functions allowed?

Comment: Fixed //char count

Comment: It would be good to actually define the sequence explicitly in the question body instead of just in the title and by linking to OEIS (the link is still good for further reference, but it shouldn't be necessary to understand the question). Likewise, if you could reproduce the first 20 or so elements as test cases, that would be good to make the challenge self-contained. It's also not clear if "produce this sequence" means to print consecutive number ad infinitum, or given `n` to return `a(n)` or to return all numbers from `a(1)` to `a(n)`.

Comment: @MB - I'll amend to repeat the title & give more examples. However I think 'an infinite list on stdout' is pretty clear?

Answer (score 0):

## Rabbit in a Snow Storm

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

### Scenario

A group member is giving a presentation in PowerPoint. He reaches a point where he wants to start writing on the whiteboard, but his slides have text that get in the way. He motions to the guy with the keyboard to just blank the screen so he can write. The next 2 minutes consist of everyone in the room bickering about how to do it until we arrive on using a full-screen-ish terminal (which is black, so we have to turn up the lights). Awful.

### Objective

Have the primary monitor become completely white.

### Rules

- You start with no programs running (or at least none that are important towards the goal)
- You may only use programs that are installed by default on your OS/distro (i.e. needs to be repeatable by someone else without installing anything in particular)
- You can't pre-load your background, slide-show, etc. with a pure-white image (though you could create the image then show it)

### Scoring

- Number of keystrokes required (keys depressed and released, i.e. opening Spotlight takes two (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>), likewise Run... (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>))
- Clicks are scored as 5 keystrokes.

Comment: In your scenario, PowerPoint is running. Yet in the rules, it isn't. I can understand if this is because the one-stroke solution `w` isn't interesting, but it still makes for a confusing question. Why not ditch PowerPoint from the scenario and replace it with a demo of some in-house software?

Comment: Oh, and you should probably add to the bit about "installed by default" that the OS hasn't learnt which programs you use, so you should assume that no auto-completion occurs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I didn't know about `w`...magical! In the scenario the guy was actually using PDF slides, so I'm not sure if Reader has the same functionality.  Good comment though, probably just forbid autocompleting?

Answer (score 0):

### Generate random seeds for strings

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
function randomString(long input) {
    accumulator = "";
    random = random.seededWith(input);
    while(true) {
        x = random.nextInteger(27); # generate integer 0-26
        if(x == 0) break;
        accumulator += x + 'a'; # add lowercase letter from a-z for values 1-26
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

In other words, this generates a random lowercase string based on a random number seed.

*Your job is not to write this behavior.*

For this golf, your job is to **REVERSE** this process. Receive a String as input, and return the random seed that would generate this string, using whatever pseudorandom algorithm is included by default in your language - so different languages will have different numbers returned for the same string.

**However,** the algorithm used to regenerate the strings should be the same for all languages.

### Fine print

You may write a [program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/17249), which [returns the output as an integer or long (whatever's appropriate for your language) or printing it to STDOUT (or closest alternative).](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) You may optionally include a single trailing newline in the output.

If the String cannot be generated in this method, your program should throw an exception and/or print an error message of some sort.

Additionally, [standard loopholes which are no longer funny](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are **banned**. You may not use external libraries unless your language doesn't support seeded random number generation by default. If that is the case, then you may use the library for random number generation that is most commonly used by that language's community.

#### Citations

This question has been brought to you by: [Why does this code using random strings print hello world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-using-random-strings-print-hello-world/15182511#15182511)

Comment: "*However, the algorithm used to regenerate the strings should be the same for all languages.*" I don't see how this can be possible, unless you're assuming either that the only way to do it is brute force (wrong) or that every standard library in the world uses linear congruential PRNGs (unlikely: there's probably some language designed by a security nut which only uses crypto PRNGs).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I meant the pseudocode should be same, not the PRNG algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

## Structural Damage Simulation

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) (either [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) or [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), haven't decided yet)

#### Introduction

In this challenge, you are given a two-dimensional map or a brick structure.
Each brick is glued to its four neighbors, and is guaranteed to be connected to the ground, that is, the bottom edge of the input grid, via adjacent bricks.
This structure is affected by gravity, which may cause some of the bricks to break, depending on their durability.
Your task is to predict whether this happens, and where.

#### Spec

The input is given as a grid of the ASCII characters `.` and `#` that represent empty space and square bricks OR a black-and-white image with the black pixels representing bricks.
You are also given a nonnegative number that represents the durability of the bricks; you can choose the valid type (integer or float) and range of this parameter and how it affects the computation.
Your output is a grid in the same format as the input, but with some of the bricks replaced by `X`s (or gray/red pixels); they represent bricks that have broken under the strain caused by the weight of the structure.

#### Example

Suppose we have the following input grid (replace with an image if that's chosen as the input format)

```
................
..######...####.
..######...####.
..########.####.
...###...#.####.
.....#...######.
.....#.....####.
.....#......#...
.....#.######...
.....#####......
.....#######....
.....#######....
```

The narrow parts of the structure are likely to break, especially the vertical ones, but the solid parts may very well hold themselves together.
A possible output would be

```
................
..######...####.
..######...####.
..######XX.####.
...###...X.####.
.....#...X#####.
.....X.....####.
.....X......X...
.....X.#XXXXX...
.....####X......
.....#######....
.....#######....
```

TODO: add more test cases.

#### Scoring

This is a popularity contest, meaning that the answer with the highest vote tally wins.
Voters are encouraged to take the following criteria into account:

- **Simplicity.** Simple and elegant algorithms are favored over complex and over-engineered ones. Elegance includes reasonable speed, so very slow algorithms are discouraged.
- **Realism.** The outputs should be close to the physical intuition of most people.
- **Flexibility.** Solutions should preferably handle complicated structures and extreme values of durability.

Answer (score 0):

## Cops 'n' Robbers - Hide a keyword in each answer [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

> This is an idea I'm still working on, but I want some feedback on whether or not it could pan out well.

#### Cops

The robbers are here! They've found our files! We, need to encrypt them! We need a certain key, something special that clearly shows what the real program is. We need to keep writing our new files, but we must keep encoding them. When a robber cracks a key, we find the key they cracked and write a new file off of that key! For example, we will hide the encryption key for file #2 in file #1, then file #2 hides a key for file #3, and so on. The files are safe if they go uncracked for 5 days, in which we win! But if the robbers crack all 100 of our files, we lose!

#### Robbers

We found the cops' files! Not only that, we cracked their encryption scheme! In file #1, they hide a key for file #2, which hides a key for file #3, and so on. Our goal is to hack all 100 files. The only catch? We'll lose our connection if we don't crack a file within 5 days.

#### In English, Please?

Basically, the cops will upload an answer with a program when the robbers crack the previous answer. The clue to the next answer is hidden in this one, encoded with the clue from the last answer. If a robber guesses wrong, that robber can not guess again on the same answer. If a answer remains uncracked for 5 days, cops win. If robbers guess all 100 answers, the robbers win.

#### Winners

The winner for the cops is whoever made the uncrackable file. For the robbers, it's whoever cracked the most files (in event of a tie, later answers are better than old ones.)

Comment: Just to be clear, each cop has to upload ***100*** files somewhere?

Comment: @Geobits No. The 'files' are the answers. The cops create 100 files (at any time) and post them (in order) as answers. The key to decode file #10 is in file #9. (File #1 will have its key posted in the question.) Robbers crack the code in a seperate thread.

Comment: The description right now is rather "themed" and isn't precise enough to explain the details of how the challenge will actually work.  Themed intros are fine, but you should write a description that, for example, uses "answers" instead of "files" and uses a team name instead of "we."

Answer (score 0):

## Astrometric Tiling

A common problem in astronomy is the stitching together of astronomical images to create a mosaic of the entire imaging survey. This can't be done by naively putting the images next to each other in a grid - they might have slightly different dimensions, and certainly have different positions & orientations, which might overlap.

The solution is to calculate the positions of the objects (usually stars) in each image in celestial coordinates, a process known as Astrometry. (This is not the challenge, as it's far too difficult for a codegolf, but if you're interested in that process, take a look at [astrometry.net](http://astrometry.net/).) Once an astrometric solution for a given image is found, every star's position on the sky can be calculated based on its position on the image.

## The Challenge

Write a program to accept lists of coordinates for some number `N>=2` of astronomical images, and output a transformation matrix for each image to create the mosaic.

## Input

You may accept either a list of coordinate lists, or a list of filenames containing coordinate lists, whichever is more convenient. The coordinate list (length >= 10) for a given image is made up of 4 coordinates per star: `x,y` in whole number pixel coordinates on the image, and `a,d` in float (requiring precision to at least 10^-5) celestial coordinates. Assume that every star's coordinates are exact, and that the same celestial coordinates in two different lists refer to the same star.

## Output

Your program should output a 3x3 [affine transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) for x,y in each image (alternatively, you can output a matrix for each image after the first, if you would like to use the first as a reference), which can be used to tile the images in such a way as to align the celestial coordinates in adjacent & overlapping images.

## Scoring

This is a (admittedly quite challenging) code golf, so shortest in bytes wins.

I'll need to produce a test case, which I will do before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a program or function that, given a [postfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) expression, converts it to the simplest equivalent expression. The expression may contain real numbers, floating variables denoted `a` to `z`, and the basic arithmetic operators `+-*/^`.

Two expressions are equivalent if they produce the same result for all possible integer values of the variables. "Simplest" means you should return the equivalent expression with the least number of operators. If there are multiple expressions with the same number of operators, pick the shortest.

### Example

Consider the expression `(8+4*y)/2+x*2`. In postfix notation, this would be

```
8,4,y,*,+,2,/,x,2,*,+
```

This should yield the output

```
2,2,y,+,x,+,*
```

which corresponds to `(2+y+x)*2`.

**Question:**

this challenge is irrelevant of code length , so i want to ask , any scoring methods i can use in this defiance

i propose : picked up nine variant expressions with different polynomial degrees , which im free to choose , tested as input for all concurrent codes , then validate the lowest sum = **(number_of_operations)^2+length(output_string)**

Answer (score 0):

## Detect limit points in (possibly) oscilating sequence

#### Popularity Contest, Algorithms

Given an (infinite) sequence of numbers, your task is to find an algorithm (and write a corresponding program) that takes the sequence as input and determines

- Whether the sequence converges to a cyclic behaviour. That means the sequence will oscillate throu one or more values, that means whether it has one or more limit points. In this case it should output the limit points.
- diverges (does not end up in one or more limit point). In this case it should output a message that says so.
- No defined behaviour for sequences that do not have acyclic limit points.

A *limit point* is a value such that for every neighbourhood of that value an infinite number of sequence elements are within that neighbourhood.

Of course you can only use a *finite* part of the sequence, so you the task is ambiguous, but the larger the given sample the better your algorithm should be able to dectect the cycles. As this is difficult to achieve for arbitrary sequences, you are allowed to use 'fine tuing parameters' that can be changed manually in order for your algorithm to work best for the given set of sequences. Please document what those parameters do.

In this case here, you can assume that the sequence will converge to a behaviour where it cycles throu all the `n` limit points without gaps (intermediate values that are not limit points) and always in the same order.

#### Motivation

You perhaps have already see this diagram (the bifurcation diagram of the logistic map)
[image]

In order to generate this diagram, you have to compute a sequence for every `r` and compute the limit points `x` of each of those sequences (which in this case are cyclic). Then you plot those `x` against `r`. The sequence is generated by the recursive function (logistic map) with a starting value `0< x(0) < 1` (usually something like `0.5`)

```
x(n+1) := r * x(n) * (1 - x(n))
```

The sequences generated this way are nice examples of the sequences that your algorithm should be able to detect.

#### Your submission

should consist of

- a function/program that executes your algorithm on a given sequence (input in any way you like),
- a description of how your algorithm works,
- and a program that uses your function for generating the bifurcation diagram above.

#### Examples

Following sequence is generated by `1+(-1)^n*(10+n)/n` This sequence does not converge in the usual sence of sequences but it has limit points at `0` and `2`. The sequence looks like this, so the

[image]

This is from the example above (logistic map with r=3.5), here we have 4 limit points:

[image]

The following sequence is bounded (and therefore has at least one limit point) but does not converge and does not seem to have a cyclic behaviour. (It is generated by `x(n) = [pi*n^3 (mod e)]/e`)

[image]

## META:

I'm happy to hear from you what you think. So far I did not find any sources that described algorithms that do exactly this task, but there may very well exist such algorithms. If you can improve the text please do so! Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you put in some example input/output? I'm still a little confused about the challenge

Comment: I know my wording is not that great, please tell me what to change! I just added some examples.

Comment: What I mean is, is the string `"1+(-1)^n*(10+n)/n"` the input, will it be the sequence of numbers generated by the expression or...?

Comment: No the input is a list of numbers (or a function that can be repeatedly called and returns the next list element or something similar), so you do not need to parse an input, the mail goal is finding an algorithm that is looking for cyclic limit points, the actuall details of the program are not that relevant. Is that clear now?

Comment: I was a bit worried that might be the case. What if you have something like `1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ... (a googol numbers later), 1, 0, 1, 0, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,... (42s forever after)`?

Comment: This is obviously a difficulty, as a reasonable algorithm can only consider a first (finite) section of the sequence, and it should find the a answer as good as possible with the given data. So the sequence `x(n) = (-1/2)^n` looks as if it is gonna be alternating between two points if you only consider lets say `x(1),...,x(5)`, but if you consider the first `100` elements it *could* become more clear that is only one. So the algorithm should basically provide a criterion to make a classification with only limited data. And the more real examples it recognises the better.

Comment: In your case as long it sees only `0,1,0,1,0,...` the algorithm should obviously return the limit points `0` and `1` (cycle length 2), but if it gets e.g. one `42` at the end of the data, it could output that the sequence does not converge. But as soon as there are *enough* `42`  it should probably say that the sequence converges to `42`. (cycle lenght 1)

Answer (score 0):

### Quaternion calculator

Quaternions are extensions of the complex number system that are used in 3d graphics and some other applications. In addition to i, there is also j and k. j^2 and k^2 are both -1, however, ij=k, jk=i, ki=j, ji=-k, kj=-i, and ik=-j. Write a calculator that can calculate addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponents. This is a code golf challenge, shortest answer wins.

EDIT: sample input: (2+4i+3j)*i^(j+2k)/(5j-i)+1

Comment: This should specify how operands and operations are given as input. However, this is a borderline duplicate. [Multiplication has already been done](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36928/8478), exponentiation can be trivially reduced to that, addition and subtraction and fairly uninteresting, so that leaves only division. So *just* doing division might be a better idea.

Comment: I had considered a sequel with division or inversion, but thought it was too likely it would be implemented as multiplying by the conjugates and rescaling by the norm, which would mostly still be about multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

## Kaos Pendulum and Einstein's Revenge

The [Double Pendulum system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is a relatively simple system with quite complex behavior that's highly sensitive to initial conditions (i.e., "chaotic").

Doctor Kaos has designed a particularly fiendish double pendulum, using his diabolical machine "Einstein's Revenge". Einstein's Revenge is a device which couples matter and energy, causing the mass of the first pendulum (connected to the anchor point) to be a function of the energy of the second: `m1 = sqrt(PE2**2 + KE2**2)`, with the potential energy measured from the rest position of the pendulum.

For this challenge, you must write a program or function to simulate a basic Kaos Pendulum, where the second pendulum has unit mass and both pendulums are unit length. It must accept the starting position of the Pendulum - two real numbers, `theta1` and `theta2` - as input or command-line arguments, and one positive integer equal to the number of seconds the pendulum will be active.

Your program must output the value of `theta1` and `theta2` for each second, either printing to stdout or returning as a list, or something similar.

### Notes

I don't know if this should be a golf, a popularity contest, or if there should be some scoring method for some other type of challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Blind (deterministic) Jenga

The idea for this came up in the chat room, under the broader topic of how to make a human dexterity game into a software KotH challenge. Here's the basic idea, which I don't think works, but I'd love to get feedback to make it better.

[image: generic jenga tower]

The jenga tower has three blocks per layer. Layers alternate between N/S aligned blocks and E/W aligned blocks.

There may be just two players, or more than two.

Each turn a player selects a block location to probe. If there's no block there, the player gets to go again. If there's a block there, it is removed from the stack. If this causes the tower to fall, the player loses. Otherwise, the block is placed in the next safe position at the top of the tower, unless all available positions are unsafe in which case the player loses. If the player has not lost, it is now the next player's turn. Continue until some player loses.

I think this won't work well because it will boil down to a relatively random competition between bots that start with edge pieces and bots that start with center pieces. I don't want to run the contest just to find out that that's the case. Maybe putting four blocks per layer would make that a non-issue. I'm open to other suggestions on how to make this challenge work.

Answer (score 0):

A [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) idea. Maybe I'll do it a long time later...

You have these options each turn (they need better names and a plausible background):

- `Meet k` If the bot k also did meet you, and nobody injects, both of your scores are increased by 1. Otherwise nothing happens. But if k is yourself, this is invalid and will be just like doing nothing.
- `Invite k` The bot k gets a notification that you are doing this, and in the next round, your output is ignored and you must do `Meet k`.
- `Inspect k` You will get these informations at the beginning of next round:

  - What the bot k was doing.
  - The score change of bot k.
  - Who was inviting bot k.
  - Who was trying to meet bot k. (This is not known by bot k if not inspecting himself and his score is not changed.)
  - Who was inspecting bot k. (This is not known by bot k if not inspecting himself.)
  - Who was injecting bot k (and another bot). (This is not known by bot k if not inspecting himself and his score is not changed.)
- `Inject j k` If j is meeting k and k is meeting j, your score is increased by 10 and their scores are both decreased by 1 instead. If one of them is pretending doing that, and the other is pretending or really doing that, your score doesn't change. Otherwise, your score is decreased by 10. They'll not know who is injecting unless they are inspecting you or self-inspecting instead.
- `DoNothing` Nothing happens.

Possible other options:

- `Pretend action`: `action` is any action other than `Pretend`. It's the same as doing nothing, but inspectors will be told that you are doing that action. The score change that the inspectors will see is calculated as if you really did that.
- `Multiply`: For each turn until the next time you meet some bot each other, the points you, the other bot and all the bots injecting you get are doubled (or incremented, I'm not sure).

Everybody can see only their own score, bots inviting them and the result from `Inspect`.

Comment: I think that Pretend is a great action, and should definitely be included.

Answer (score 0):

## Is this a red-black tree?

A red-black tree is a binary search tree where each node has an additional 'colour' property, which can be black or red. The root and leaf nodes must be black, each red node must have black children, and the path from any node to any child leaves must have the same number of black nodes. For instance:

```
2B
|  \
1R  3B
|   |
~   ~
```

Is invalid because of a black violation (the path from the root to each leaf has a different number of blacks).

Your task is to determine whether a given tree is a valid Red-Black tree.

### Input

The input will be a string matching `[ a-zA-Z]`. A space represents a leaf, a lowercase character a black node, and an uppercase character a red node. The value of a node is the position in the alphabet: a is 0, b is 1, C is 2, and so on. The children of the node in position `n` are in positions `2n+1` and `2n+2`. If the string ends before the position you're looking for, that node is a leaf. For instance, `baD  cf      E` corresponds to:

```
       1,B

     /     \

 0,B         3,R

           /     \

       2,B         5,B

                 /

             4,R
```

### Output

Your program should output something other than whitespace on STDOUT if and only if the input represents a valid tree.

### Simple test cases

```
True      False
" "       ""        (Root black violation)
"a"       "A"       (Root black violation)
"cAD"     "cAB"     (Order violation)
"dBeac"   "dBea"    (Black violation)
          "dAE B"   (Red violation)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question about extrapolating data from an incomplete tennis scoreboard**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Introduction**

It is a fine day at the Stack Exchange tennis club. The players have just finished playing a grand tennis tournament in a round robin style (every player plays every other player once). The final results were about to be announced when suddenly, the scoreboard explodes! It is a total disaster - now nobody knows what the final scores were! Luckily, a piece of the scoreboard is still intact. Can you write a program to figure out the rest of the scoreboard from only a small part of it?

If there are `k` players, our scoreboard would have had `k*3` entries, indicating each player's **wins**, **losses**, and **draws**. It is presented in a list of space separated comma separated tuples. For instance, in a game with 4 players here is a possible final scoreboard:

```
0,2,1 3,0,0 1,1,1 1,2,0
```

In this example the first player did not win anything, lost twice, and drew once; the second player won all three of their matches; the third player won once, lost once, and drew once; and the fourth player won once and lost twice.

**Input Description**

As input, you are given a scoreboard similar to the one above, except **some of the numbers have been replaced by `?`**. The `?` indicate the numbers that were unrecoverable after the explosion. For instance:

```
?,?,1 0,?,0 ?,?,?
```

**Output Description**

Output the scoreboard, with the `?`s replaced with the actual scores. The input scoreboard will always have enough information for you to deduce the final scoreboard.

For example, consider the above input. We know that the second player has 0 wins and 0 draws, therefore, they must have lost both of their games. The first player has a single draw, and since we know the first player beat the second player, that draw must be with the third player. Thus the output is:

```
1,0,1 0,2,0 1,0,1
```

**Sample inputs and outputs**

```
TODO: Sample inputs and outputs of higher k
```

**Sandbox Questions**

- I have an alternate formulation for this question where instead of an incomplete scoreboard, the complete scoreboard is given and the program has to generate a table of which player beat which player. Which challenge do you think would be more interesting?

Answer (score 0):

**Sudoku Swapping Shenanigans**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)?

Honestly, there's not many shenanigans in this challenge but I wanted that sweet tautogram title.

**Introduction**

Imagine you're on a train, and there is a Sudoku grid that's already been entirely filled in left on the seat. We'll represent this grid as a series of 81 comma separated integers from `1-9` on a single line. Each cell in the grid can be numbered as follows:

[image: not another sudoku puzzle...]

As with all Sudoku grids, there will be exactly 9 of each number present in the input.

The Sudoku grid will not be completed correctly. It will have the right number of each number, but they will be positioned wrong. Your program's task is to *swap* these numbers to solve the Sudoku puzzle correctly.

(Since your stop is next, you want to make this program solve the Sudoku puzzle as fast as possible.)

or:

(Since you're writing this program on a napkin, you want to make it use as little bytes as possible.)

**Input Description**

Input consists of 81 positive integers that are comma separated. Some of them will be prefixed with an `X` which means those are the ones that are already placed and you can't swap them.

Example input goes here.

**Output Description**

Output the swaps required to solve the grid in the fewest number of swaps. You should have a line for each swap, consisting of two numbers in the form:

```
a,b
```

where `a` and `b` are both different and in the range `0-80`.

Here's an example output (and I haven't actually written the example input yet!)

```
80,0
8,9
14,15
```

So that would mean that to solve the grid we need to swap the number in position 80 with the number in position 0, the number in position 8 with the number in position 9, etc.

**Sandbox Questions**

- Not sure if it should be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code). Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are we trying to solve it in the *fewest* number of swaps, or just transform it into *any* solved sudoku grid (meaning I could swap every input into a single predetermined pattern)?

Comment: @Geobits Fewest number of steps.

Comment: Do you guarantee that the original clues give a unique solution? If so, there's a lot of overlap with existing Sudoku-solver questions, and fastest-code would need a very large and well-chosen set of test cases to be confident that it's not overly sensitive to the order in which heuristics are applied. The interesting (IMO) part of the question reduces to "Decompose a non-simple graph into cycles", and I think there may be better settings to present it.

Answer (score 0):

Code golf challenge: Write a program or a function that solves the following problem. Normal code-golf rules apply.

Given a set of subnets, give the smallest possible network these can belong to. You should consider the network- and broadcast addresses in your calculations.

Example input:

```
128.208.0.0/18
128.208.128.0/17
128.208.96.0/19
```

Example output:

```
128.208.0.0/16
```

You might want to read up on IP prefixes before trying this.

Comment: This may be too similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48175/ipv4-subnet-list-cleaner-in-cidr-notation

Answer (score 0):

## Flash Cards Viewer

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In this challenge, your goal is to produce a flash card viewer. Since this is a Code Golf challenge, it won't be a particularly featureful flash card viewer - in fact, it'll be the bare minimum a flash card viewer can be. We'll implement the following features:

1. Reading a list of flash cards from a file;
2. Quizzing the user on either "side" of the flash cards;
3. Reporting to the user which ones they got incorrect.

**Input Description**

As feature number 1 suggests, for this challenge you must read input from a file (unfortunately, your language cannot participate if it does not support reading from a file). The file shall be called `cards.txt` and will be formatted as a simple list of values separated by a pipe character `|`. For instance, a "Family Names in Chinese" flash card deck might look like this:

```
Mother|妈妈
Father|爸爸
Elder Sister|姐姐
Younger Sister|妹妹
Older Brother|哥哥
Younger Brother|弟弟
```

**Output Description**

First, your program should ask the user which side of the cards they want to revise, using a user input function such as `prompt()` or `raw_input()`. An input of `0` indicates the user wants to revise the left side of the cards, and an input of `1` indicates the user wants to revise the right side of the cards. Use the message `"Choose side:"` when asking the user.

After that, the program will pick out random entries from the opposite side of the user's selection, and prompt the user to type in the entry's corresponding value. After the user has gone through the entire list, output the pairs that he or she got incorrect.

Here is an example of what a possible session might look like. What the user inputted in this example is signified with `>`.

```
Choose side:
>0
妹妹
>Younger Sister
妈妈
>Mother
爸爸
>Father
哥哥
>Younger Brother
弟弟
>Older Brother
Older Brother|哥哥
Younger Brother|弟弟
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fibonacci Box Packing Factory

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci)

#### Introduction

*The Electronic Goods Company* is a company that produces electronic item of various sizes. They need to package their items in boxes so that they can be shipped off to the store. There are some restrictions regarding what item can be stored in what box:

1. Each box can only contain a single item, and each item can only be contained in one box;
2. The volume of the item cannot exceed the volume of the box;
3. If the volume of the item is exactly the volume of the box, the item can be placed in the box without any padding material required;
4. If the volume of the item is less than the volume of the box, then padding material equal to the difference of volumes must be placed in the box to prevent the item breaking.

For example, an item that had a volume of 2m<sup>3</sup> could be placed in a box of volume 2m<sup>3</sup> without any extra padding material, but if the same item was placed in a box of volume 5m<sup>3</sup>, we'd need to add padding material of 3m<sup>3</sup>.

The supplier company is called the Fibonacci Box Company, which supplies The Electronics Goods Company with `N` boxes and `P` metres squared of filling material. Each box's volume is determined by the Fibonacci sequence (so the first box's volume is `1`, the second is also `1`, the third is `2`, the fourth is `3`, the fifth is `5`, etc.).

Your program goal is to figure out the minimum amount of padding material required to pack all of the electronic items.

#### Input Description

Input is a space separated list of integers that indicate the volume in square metres of the electronic items.

```
//TODO: Example inputs and outputs
```

#### Output Description

Output the minimum value of `P` required to fill all the boxes.

```
//TODO: Example inputs and outputs
```

Comment: I'm assuming that items can't be split between multiple boxes, and that a box can't contain multiple items?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yep. Rule 1 states only one item can be placed in each box. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: A couple example would help understand the challenge. You could also add some explanation to them. E.g. `1 5 8 7 => 6 (N = 7, boxes = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13, used boxes = 1 5 8 13)` if I understand it correctly. Volume is cubic metres, m3.

Answer (score 0):

## NP Cops and Robbers

This is an idea I've had for a while, and I really want to get it to work, but there are some large hurdles.

Hurdle 1: I need to pick a puzzle, preferably one that is NP-Complete. I think lots of Nikoli puzzles are good candidates, and I am leaning towards [Light Up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_Up_(puzzle))

## Cops:

Cops will write a program to generate a puzzle.  The puzzle has a maximum size of WxH.  The cops must be able to generate the puzzle in under 1 second.  Puzzles must be deterministic, but randomness is allowed as long as I can set the seed.  The puzzles generated must have only 1 solution.  The cop will post a sample puzzle in his post (for the robbers to use)

Your score is the shortest time any of the robbers solved your puzzle.  Highest score wins.

## Robbers:

Robbers write programs to solve the puzzles.  Robbers are not allowed to target the specific puzzles, but are allowed to target the specific algorithms used to generate the puzzle.  If the cop were to change the sample puzzle posted, the robber should still be able to solve the new puzzle in a similar amount of time.

If you solve a puzzle faster than any other robber, your score increases by the time taken to solve that puzzle.  Highest score wins.

Hurdle 2: How to measure time taken.  I don't want to run all of the cops/robbers, especially if this becomes popular.  I also don't want to use the GOLF framework, as that would take a really long time to run.  So, possible I could have the person run som CPU-intesive algorithm on their computer, measure how long it takes, and scale all of their answers according to that time.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a basic spell checker

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
In this challenge, you have to implement a basic spell checker. Your program will use the first input as a source.

### Specifications

- You will receive two inputs, one is a sentence/paragraph you use as a source for your spell checker, and the other includes wrong words (they can be correct too) which you have to correct using the first input.
- Possible mistakes: Missing one letter (e.g. helo), one extra letter (e.g. heello), substitution of one character (e.g. hilp instead of help), transposition of two adjacent characters (e.g. hlep instead of help).
- In other words, the mistake and the original word have to have a Damerau–Levenshtein distance of one.
- You can separate the inputs in any reasonable format. For example, instead of using a newline, you can use a pipe sign to separate them. (|) However, watch out so you don't use something like letters because they are used in the 1st input.
- It's possible for a word to have neither an identical word nor a word with 1 distance from the first input. You will have to leave them unchanged.
- You don't need to do anything with punctuation. That is, I won't test words that are followed by a punctuation. (E.g. From the first example, I won't ask the correction of 'blod')
- Challenge is case insensitive, both the input and output. Meaning that if 'The' is used in the 1st input and the 2nd input is 'teh' you can change it to 'The', 'teh', 'teH', and similar cases.
- If a word is in the first input, but also has a distance of 1 with one of the other words, do not correct it.
- If there are two words with the same distance, you can output either of them. (E.g. 'en' can change into 'on' and 'in' if the words are both in the first input.) You can also output both of them, but you'll have to use a slash between them. (E.g. 'en' can be corrected into 'in/on')
- You can assume words are just sequences of letters separated by spaces.
- You can use STDIN or the closest alternative in your language.
- [Standard loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

### Examples

Input:

```
A criminal strain ran in his blood, which, instead of being modified, was increased and rendered infinitely more dangerous by his extraordinary mental powers. 

increasd mnetal
```

Output:

```
increased mental
```

Input:

```
The fact is that upon his entrance I had instantly recognized the extreme personal danger in which I lay.

I recognizi dnger en
```

Output:

```
I recognize danger in
```

Comment: There are several definitions of "distance". Since the most common one is probably Levenshtein, you might want to specifically say that original and mistake have to have [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) of one. Other questions: what is a word? Only sequences of letters? What about "doesn't" or "up-to-date"? (It's probably simplest to rule those out.) What do we output if there are two different words with distance one? E.g. does `en` become `in` or `on` if both are in the first string?

Comment: Is the input case insensitive? If so, is case of the output arbitrary too or do we have to preserve the input capitalisation? And are we guaranteed that every word in the second string *has* a word in the first string that is no more than distance 1 away?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I clarified it in the bullet point above it. Only transposition of adjacent letters, one missing letter, one extra letter and a wrong letter. I guess that's Damerau-Levenshtein distance. Regarding the two words problem, I guess you could output either of them. I'm not really sure about this. I'm open for ideas.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good point. It's case insensitive, and the output can be in any case. (e.g. If the first input includes 'The' and there's 'teh' in the second input, it should output 'the' or 'THE' or 'tHE' or ...). No, you're not guaranteed that there's a word with a distance of 1 in the first input. Take a look at the example #2, 'I' was not changed. Also, in your previous post, you asked what counts as a word. I already said it in the post 'You can assume all words in the 2nd input are separated by spaces.' I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: I was asking for distance "no more than 1 away". That is, could there be a word that has neither a word with distance 1 nor an identical word in the first input? "You can assume words are just sequences of letters separated by spaces." Yet in the first input, there is punctuation. What sort of punctuation should we expect? The rest looks good.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, it's possible for a word to have neither an identical word nor a word with 1 distance from the 1st input. You can ignore the words that are followed by a punctuation, like blood in the 1st input. They won't be in the test cases. (E.g. I won't ask for the correction of 'blod') Thank you for your help.

Comment: As for the 'lay' in the first example, I'll fix it now, thanks.

Comment: Right, but the question is what do we do with words that have neither an identical word nor a word with 1 distance from the 1st input. Remove them? Leave them changed? Also, that second point might be worth mentioning in the spec.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Leave them unchanged. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiply with restricted operations: Best lower bound

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

[Multiply with restricted operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37188/20260) is a challenge to multiply two variables using as few as possible of four allowed operations: addition, reciprocal, negation, and variable assignment. The current best is [22 operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41314/20260).

Your goal is to prove a lower bound `L`, a number for which you demonstrate that there are no solutions with fewer that `L` operations. The highest `L` wins.

You must explain why your code demonstrates the lower bound, and I must be able verify your code by running it. There is a time limit of 30 minutes. The natural approach is to search the space of possible solutions, perhaps shrinking it via mathematical arguments, but any method is allowed. Purely mathematical proofs without code are also valid.

Your code is limited to 30 minutes and 3GB of memory on my machine (Windows 7 with a Intel Core i5-460M processor). I may be satisfied with someone else running your code to confirm with a conservative adjustment for different machine speeds.

Your code needs to run on easily-available free software. Please include instructions on how to run your code.

The winner will be the highest lower-bound proven by [date]. Tiebreak is fastest runtime on my computer. I will give a **bounty of 500 rep** to the winner.

If your lower bound matches a solution, narrowing down the optimum to a single value, I will award you an [additional bounty of 300 rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37188/multiply-with-restricted-operations).

---

**For Sandbox:**

- I haven't done a fastest code before. Anything I'm missing? Any machine specs I should add?
- When to have deadline?

Comment: Maybe you should require the program to be able to prove lower bounds for arbitrary expressions, rather than only a*b. Otherwise, it will be impossible to tell if a brute-forcing program is doing anything correctly, for any bound too low to find an answer.

Comment: @feersum I'd really like to let people optimize for just multiplication since that's the function I care about. Is it really impractical to verify that code is doing the search correctly if the user is required to give a detailed explanation of their method and why it works? I trust people to be honest as to what the code does.

Comment: I do believe it is impractical. How can you really tell that someone is not randomly twiddling bits and then printing 19? It seems that (innocently) bugged answers are more likely than correct ones in an environment where there is no testing.

Answer (score 0):

## Date-A-List!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)

#### Introduction

The year is 20XX. Lists of integers are now members of society with a full set of rights. Like humans, lists like to have dates and get married. In this challenge, we'll produce a program "Date-A-List!" that will get as many lists as possible on happy and compatible dates. Lists tend to prefer using programs that use as little bytes as possible, so this program will be golfed.

Lists are *compatible* (that is, you can assign them to a date together) if they share 2 or more integers in the same order. For instance, the lists `(1 2 3)` and `(2 3 5)` would be compatible. The lists `(1 2 3)` and `(3 2 5)` would not be compatible because they do not share 2 or more integers that are in the same order.

Lists are also always monogamous -- they will never go on a date with more than one list. For instance, consider the lists `(1 2 3)`, `(2 3 5)` and `(5 1 2)` -- although the first list is compatible with both of the others, it may only date one of them.

#### Input Description

Input is a list of lists in brackets, space separated:

```
(1 2 3) (2 3 5) (5 1 2)
```

That input would indicate three lists to be assigned to dates: `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3, 5]`, and `[5, 1, 2]`.

#### Output Description

If `n` is the maximum number of dates possible, output `n` lines, each line consisting of two space separated lists which are to be matched up. For instance, on the example input there are two possible outputs:

```
(1 2 3) (2 3 5)
```

or:

```
(1 2 3) (5 1 2)
```

*[TODO: More complex inputs and outputs]*

Comment: It would be nice to include the word "matching" somewhere in the text, for searchability. It would also be nice to have the basic examples use slightly more variety: at present they're all 3-element lists which overlap on adjacent pairs, but neither of those are stated as constraints. How about using `(1 2 3)` and `(2 5 4 3)` as the example of compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

## 5-a-side Toroidal Bot Soccer

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

### Randomised teams

This is a team game. Rather than being assigned permanently to one team or the other, each bot will play in a number of games, each for a different randomly composed team of 5 players ("5-a-side"), and score a point for each game in which its team wins. This means every game requires team work, but there is still a single overall winner after all games are played.

### Rules

There are no rules for the players (no referee, no penalties, no off-side rule). The movement of the ball defines the score and the players can do as they see fit.

#### Scoring

There are no goal posts. If the ball moves off the right hand edge of the field, it reappears at the left hand edge of the field and team 1 scores a goal. Similarly team 2 score if it moves off the left hand edge and reappears at the right. The score will be represented by a single integer, that is increased by one when team 1 scores, and decreased by one when team 2 scores. At the end of a game, team 1 wins if the score is positive, team 2 wins if the score is negative, and a zero score is a draw/tie.

Movement over the top and bottom edges has no effect on the score.

The game lasts for 2000 time steps (each bot provides 2000 moves). If there is no winner by the end of the game it is extended by up to a further 1000 moves, with the game ending if either team scores.

### Physics

Physics is the main obstacle to real world toroidal soccer, and will not be respected in this game. The physics have been simplified as much as possible to hopefully allow games to be viewed live.

This is a non-contact sport. Bots pass straight through other bots (of either team) with no interaction. Each bot can only interact with the ball.

The playing field is a continuous rectangle of width 100 and height 50. The bots and the ball have radius 1. Bots and ball can move freely in any direction without meeting a boundary - the edges of the field wrap. The ball will rebound from any bot if their circumferences overlap.

#### Turning and acceleration

Due to the use of simplified physics this is quick to explain:

A bot has a facing angle and a velocity. A constant acceleration applies in the direction specified by the facing angle. Drag is a deceleration proportional to the velocity (an acceleration in the opposite direction to the velocity, proportional to the size of the velocity). This means a bot that does not turn will accelerate to a maximum velocity where the drag matches the acceleration.

A bot can turn any angle instantaneously, but the velocity (and hence direction) will only change gradually. For example, a bot changing direction by 180 degrees will continue travelling backwards while it slows down to zero velocity, and then accelerate in its new direction.

The ball has no acceleration of its own, so other than collisions, its only change in velocity is due to drag. There is no spin.

#### Collisions

Only the ball can be involved in a collision with a bot - bots pass straight through each other.

Although the radius of both bots and ball will be displayed visually as 1, I believe the results are the same if collision calculations are based on the bots having radius 2 and the ball being a point.

To keep calculation simple, the ball will be tested for collision with each bot by considering the bot to be a circle moving with constant velocity and the ball to be a point moving with constant velocity (that is, the acceleration will occur at instants, rather than continuously over time). Since this is also how the motion will be modelled generally, the collisions should be consistent with the motion of objects in the game.

This allows the exact point of collision to be calculated so the rebound can occur with no overlap.

### Communication

*There is no communication between bots. Each bot communicates solely with the controller.*

The communication method will depend on the controller type (language agnostic/specific). Players will either be functions/objects in a specific language, or separate programs that communicate through STDIN/STDOUT.

Each step all bots will be supplied with the same information, and will provide a facing angle which will be a float in the range [0, 360).

The information supplied to bots will be as follows.

- Team direction (`1` for team 1 or `-1` for team 2)
- Current score (positive if team 1 is winning, negative if team 2 is winning)
- Facing angle and velocity of itself
- Facing angle and velocity of 4 team mates
- Facing angle and velocity of 5 opponents

Facing angle will be given as a float.
Velocity will be given as x and y components, so two floats.

The information will therefore be received as two integers followed by 15 floats.

---

## Sandbox questions

- Are any terms not familiar that would be worth linking or further explaining?
- Are there any further simplifications that could be made, without detracting from the game?
- Are any of the simplifications too much? Am I overlooking some way in which the game could become trivial?
- Is it correct to model the bots as radius 2 and the ball as a point? Does this give identical results to modelling the bots as radius 1 and the ball as radius 1?
- Are there any problems likely to arise from basing collision detection on constant velocity bots and ball? (Acceleration being applied instantaneously each step, rather than spread out over continuous time.)

Comment: How long does each game last for? I like your idea of randomising the teams. How many bots are in each team?

Comment: @TheE The "5-a-side" in the title refers to 5 players per team - I wasn't sure how widely known that was so I'll edit that in.

Comment: @TheE I'm not sure how long each game should last yet - I'll have to test with some example players once the controller is written. For now I'll say 2000 steps in order to have something that people can comment on. I guess it will depend on what acceleration and drag figures I settle on too - as that affects how far each bot can move per time step.

Comment: If a player of the right team stays on the left part of the field, he could counter score every goal it's team take, right?

Comment: Yeah I didn't read the title :) oops

Comment: @TheE no problem - and thanks for the other feedback :)

Comment: @Katenkyo all the players can move freely over the edges of the field, so if the left team can get the ball past the right team's players then it shouldn't matter which side of the field they are on. The left team can reappear at the left side of the field and keep kicking the ball further right.

Comment: @Katenkyo also all players can see all other players, so a bot from team 1 kicking the ball past the right hand edge of the field can see any team 2 bots waiting at the left hand edge of the field. It can therefore aim to avoid them so they cannot simply kick it back.

Answer (score 0):

## One transparent colour sprite

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

### Overview

**This challenge will only involve a hex string as input and a hex string as output, but will be explained in terms of computer graphics.**

**Given a fixed size background image, a smaller fixed size sprite image and its location, place the sprite on the background image allowing the background to show through for one specified colour of the sprite image.**

---

### Details

- The background image will always be 32 by 18 pixels.
- The sprite image will always be 8 by 8 pixels.
- The colours will always be in the range 0 to 3 inclusive.
- There will always be exactly one transparent colour, from 0 to 3 inclusive.
- The location (x, y) of the sprite may be outside or partially outside the background image.

### Input

Since all inputs will always be the same size, there will be no separators, just a single string of hex digits.

To avoid having to define negative inputs, the top left pixel of the background image will be (128, 128), increasing left and down, and x and y will be defined by 2 hex digits each, giving a range of 0 to 255.

The input hex string will be made up of:

- Background pixels, 2 per hex digit, a string of 32 * 18 * 0.5 = 288
- Sprite pixels, 2 per hex digit, a string of 8 * 8 * 0.5 = 32
- Transparent colour, a single hex digit (the most significant half of the hex digit is unused)
- Sprite x and y, 2 hex digits each, a string of 2 * 2 = 4

The input will therefore be a string of 288 + 32 + 1 + 4 = 325 hex digits with no separators.

### Output

The output is the finished 32 by 18 pixel image, as a string of 288 hex digits with no separators.

### Format

#### Pixel order

Each image is ordered in English reading order, left to right then top to bottom. That is, the pixels are listed in rows. The first pixel listed will be the top left. This applies to both the background image and the sprite image.

#### Colour encoding

Pixel colours are encoded 2 per hex digit, most significant first.

For example, the hex digit B corresponds to binary 1011. This means the first pixel has value 10 = 2 and the second pixel has value 11 = 3.

#### Transparent colour

Since the single transparent colour is encoded in one hex digit, which normally holds 2 colours, the first 2 bits (most significant) are ignored and the last 2 bits (least significant) are used to represent the transparent colour.

For example, the hex digit D corresponds to binary 1101. The 11 is ignored and the 01 is used to indicate colour 1.

Although the first two binary digits are always ignored, you may not assume they are always 00. They may take any value and all hex inputs of the correct length should produce a valid output.

#### Coordinates

x and y are encoded as 2 hex digits each, most significant first.

For example, the hex string 2A corresponds to binary 00101010, and decimal 42

#### Case sensitivity

Your code may accept input as either upper case or lower case hex digits, or both. If it only accepts one or the other case, it must also output in the same case.

You may not choose an arbitrary 16 characters to represent hexadecimal. You must use either (or both) of the following as input:

```
0123456789abcdef

0123456789ABCDEF
```

You must choose one or other (*not* both/mixed) to use as output. That is, you may accept inconsistent inputs if you wish to, but the output must be either always lower case or always upper case.

---

## Sandbox thoughts

- I'm considering adding example inputs and outputs and maybe a snippet to verify the output of arbitrary inputs for testing.

Answer (score 0):

## Build a Rorschach Generator

2 possible challenges:

### 1.

Help a [poor struggling game dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102779/66398) write some code to quickly and efficiently generate a Rorschach inkblot.

Using your language of choice, generate a Rorschach inkblot. You may use any method of generating a random seed.

The generated image must be in black and white and reflect down the middle of the image. This is a code golf so the shortest submission will win.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

OR

### 2.

Help a [poor struggling game dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102779/66398) write some code to quickly and efficiently generate a Rorschach inkblot.

Given 2 input images (a source image and an image of a *template* inkblot), convert the first into the Rorschach inkblot of the second without changing the colours of the image.

You may assume that the images are the same size, however you may not display the original image unaltered. Anywhere in the template where the RGB values of the pixel are (255,255,255), you may not display the original image. The produced image must be vertically mirrored, so you will have 2 copies of the source image distorted and reflected in the result.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

*Then I'd provide source images some of which would probably be shamelessly stolen from either the [Voroni Map](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50299/16043) or the [Mona Lisa Colour Palette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33172/16043) questions because those questions are awesome.*

*My thoughts*:

I'm essentially hoping to get the source image in a twisted demented fragmented form, similar to if you gave a small child red cordial then the source image and a blur tool and said go nuts. I feel like my second challenge has potential, but I feel like I need to improve the challenge description and detail exactly what I want to be produced, but I'm not sure how to do that without a wall of text and without unnecessarily restricting the challenge.

Comment: Your suggestions aren't code-golf. Code-golf means that the shortest code in byte/char wins. First of all, you should determine what will be the winning criterion. It will be hard to determine some if you want to keep it as a code-golf AND a pop-con. The first one is more designed to be a pop-con, as submissions can be creative. The second one is too restrictive to be a pop-con : for the same images, ouput will always be the same. It would go as a code-golf. Be aware that image-processing is language retrictive by essence, and that could be badly welcomed as a code-golf :)

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but something to look over to make sure yours differs sufficiently [Make a Rorschach image](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/what-do-you-see-in-an-inkspot-rorschach-generation)

Answer (score 0):

## [Insert] Nerd Sniping Pattern (Series)

Having learned from [Prime Nerd Sniping Pattern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51972/prime-nerd-sniping-pattern) that hoping an optimal solution will not be spotted too quickly is not a good idea, I'd like to judge how much interest there is in a series of similar contests that have been demonstrated to not have an achievable optimal solution, allowing long term open ended competition.

Each one would need work to demonstrate this lack of an achievable optimal solution, and I'll put that work in if there is suffficient interest here.

For example, there could be a Fibonacci Nerd Sniping Pattern, Factorial Nerd Sniping Pattern, and so on. Each one would need to have a different method of defining the scoring pattern, so that different optimisation techniques and algorithms would be required for each one. This is what would ensure they are distinguished from each other as separate challenges in a series, rather than near duplicates.

## What I've learned from my mistake with the primes

The prime scoring pattern had a checkerboard optimal solution because all of the scoring pixels were on opposite coloured checkerboard squares to the pixel being scored. I need to avoid this in any future scoring patterns, and more generally avoid any pattern that divides the image into two regions for scoring (where all of one region are scored by combinations of pixels from the other). Intuitively, there should be plenty of mixing.

As I think about it more, I'll add ideas here on things to rule out and things to ensure I have before considering a pattern scoring rule ready for posting.

Answer (score 0):

## Build a Mahjong AI

Mahjong is a traditional Chinese gambling game played throughout Asia in which four players draw and discard tiles in order to try to complete a hand of 14 tiles.

In [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/what-are-you-waiting-for-a-mahjong-solver), a specification for a simplified version of Mahjong called "PPCG Mahjong" was given. Your task in this problem is to build a program that will play a version defined here called "Full PPCG Mahjong" (hereafter known as the FPM rules).

Your program will be an *online program*, taking input as it plays the game. (that does not necessarily mean it needs networking capabilities, but it means that it will output in reaction to ongoing input, not just all input at once.)

### Tiles

There are 34 types of tiles in FPM.

1. The “bǐng”/“pin” (餅) tiles, also known as the circle tiles / dot tiles. These will be represented in text with a number from `1` to `9` and then the letter `b`, as in `1b`, `2b`, up to `9b`.
2. The “suǒ”/“sou” (索) tiles, also known as the bamboo tiles. These will be  represented in text with a number from `1` to `9` and then the letter `s`, as in `1s`, `2s`, up to `9s`.
3. The “wàn”/“man” (萬) tiles, also known as the character tiles. These will be represented in text with a number from `1` to `9` and then the letter `w`, as in `1w`, `2w`, up to `9w`.

The three tile types totalling 27 tiles above are called the *number tiles*.

4. The “fēng”/”fuu” (風) tiles, also known as the wind tiles. There is one wind tile for each cardinal direction. These will be represented in text with the letter of the wind's cardinal direction in capitals, repeated twice, as in: `EE`, `SS`, `WW`, or `NN`.
5. The “yuán”/“gen” (元) tiles, also known as the dragon tiles. There is one red, one green, and one white dragon, represented as `ZZ` (for *zhōng* 中/center), `FF` (for *fā* 發/fortune), and `BB` (for *bái* 白/white) respectively.

The two tile types above are called the *honour tiles*. There are four of each type of tile, for a total of 136 tiles.

### Objective

The goal of Mahjong is to form a complete hand, which consists of four sets and a pair.

A set is one of:

- A *sequence* of number tiles. (e.g. `5w 6w 7w` or `3s 4s 5s`)
- A *triplet* of any tile (number or honour tile). (e.g. `3b 3b 3b` or `EE EE EE`)
- A *quadruplet* of any tile. (e.g. `3b 3b 3b 3b` or `EE EE EE EE`)

A complete hand will have 14 tiles if there are no quadruplets present; each quadruplet adds one tile to the hand's size, up to a possible 18.

### Gameplay

Mahjong is a game played in several *hands* (局, *jú*).

At the beginning of each hand, each player receives a text input of `START [Wind] [Round number]`. Each player is then given an input of 13 tiles, represented as a set of 13 space-separated strings (e.g. `1b 9s BB 3w 6w 4b ZZ 3w 5w 2s 6b NN NN`) and assigned a different *seat wind* depending on where they "sit" at the virtual table (given as a single letter out of `NESW`).

Starting with the player at position East and moving clockwise around the compass, each player takes a *turn* in which:

- The player whose turn it is will be given a tile (自摸牌, *zìmōpái*) from the "wall" (the collection of tiles that have not been drawn or dealt yet) as a two-character input.
- The player can take actions during the standby phase:

  - If the player has four of the same tile in his hand, it can call *kong* (槓, *gàng*) and draw an extra tile. Those tiles must stay as a quadruplet from then on and cannot be used for anything else. The program does this by outputting `kong [quadruplet tile]` as text.
  - If the player previously called pung on a triplet and has a fourth of the tile, it can call *kong* as well.
  - If the player's hand is complete with this drawn tile, it may declare *hu* in which case the hand ends.
- The player will then produce an output of whatever tile it decides to discard. The tile that was discarded will be propagated as output to the other players in the form `[seat] [discarded tile]` (e.g. `E 8w`). The players can then *call* that tile if it will complete a set:

  - The player immediately after the discarding player may call *chi* (吃, *chī*) by outputting `chi` as text during the call phase, to complete a sequence.
  - Any other player can call *pung* (碰, *pèng*) to complete a triplet, similarly by outputting `pung` as text. Pung overrides chi when it happens.
  - Any player can also call *kong* (槓, *gàng*) to complete a quadruplet,  also by outputting text, in which case they are given an extra tile as text input.
  - Any player can also call *hu* (胡, *hú*) to complete their hand regardless of whether they are completing a sequence, triplet, or pair. Hu overrides both pung/kong and chi.
  - If a player does not want to call tiles, it must output `pass`.

The turn immediately goes to the player who called the tile, and they skip their draw phase, discarding another tile immediately. If nobody called a tile, the next player draws one. At any point if a player calls, the other three players will receive an input indicating that the player in that seat made a call and what was called.

- For chi, the input will be in the form of `[seat] chi [other two tiles]` (e.g. `S chi 6w 7w`).
- For pung and kong, the input will be in the form of `[seat] pung/kong`. This is because all the tiles are identical to the called tile anyway.
- For hu, the input will be in the form of `[seat] hu [all other tiles in hand]`.

In the above three cases, the tile being called is always the previously discarded tile.

- For a kong during the standby phase, the input will be in the form of `[seat] kong [kong tile]`, because the kong tile is not implied to be the previously discarded tile.
- For a hu during the standby phase, the input will be in the form of `[seat] hu [tile drawn]`

Once a tile is called, the set that it makes is locked in place and cannot change for the rest of the hand. So if two tiles would make use of a tile in a called set, they may not use that tile.

A hand ends when either somebody calls *hu* validly or there are no more tiles to draw. (There is no dead wall in this game.) At that point, all players will receive an input of `END` to signal that the round has ended, and a summary of their points.

If somebody other than the dealer won, then the deal rotates. If the dealer or nobody won, then the deal stays the same. After four deal rotations, the prevailing wind also rotates.

A game of FPM consists of 16 such deal-rotations (rounds), such that each player gets to play one round with each combination of seat wind and table wind. Each player starts with a bank of 500 points. At the end of 16 rounds, the player with the most points is the winner of the game.

### Example gameplay interaction

```
> START HAND EAST 1
> 1b 4b 6b 2s 9s 3w 3w 5w 6w NN NN ZZ BB
> E       // The player is East (dealer)
> NN      // East drew the north-wind first.
BB        // East decides to discard the white-dragon.
> S 3w    // Nobody called it, and South discards a 3-character.
pung      // East wants to pung the 3w tile.
ZZ        // East discards the red-dragon
> S pung  // South pungs the red-dragon.
> S 6w    // South discards a 6-character instead.
pass      // East has no use for this tile, so it passes.
> W kong 2s    // West declares a standby kong on 2-bamboo.
> W 3b    // West discards a 3-circle.
pass      // East passes again.
> N chi 2b 4b  // North chi-s it with a 2b and 4b.
> N 7s    // North discards a 7-bamboo.
pass
> 2w      // East's hand: 1b 4b 6b 2s 9s 2w 5w 6w NN NN NN -- 3w 3w 3w
2w        // East doesn't need the 2w, so he discards it.
> S hu 2b 3b 4b 7s 8s 9s 2w 6w 7w 8w ZZ ZZ ZZ 
          // South wins on that tile. The 2w completed his pair.
> END
> 496 506 499 499  // Their current point counts. South's hand was worth
                   // 2 points, so East pays 4 while the others pay 1.
> START EAST 2
> [13 more tiles]
> N       // The deal rotated, and this player is now North.
```

### Brackets

Your program can participate in one of three levels of gameplay:

- Level 1, where every hand is worth exactly 8 points, and the only thing that matters is completing hands.
- Level 2, where every hand is worth the number of points in the points table section below, but any hand can still win.
- Level 3, where every hand is worth the number of points in the points table, but a hand must have at least 8 points total with that system to win.

### Points

(TBD)

### Penalties

The following are invalid moves:

- Failing to produce an output when required.
- Discarding a tile that is not in your hand, or when it is not your turn.
- Calling chi on any player other than the one immediately before you, or calling any tile that does not actually complete a set in your hand.
- Calling hu when your hand is not complete, or when your hand value does not meet the minimum point requirement in level 3 gameplay.

If your program makes an invalid move, the move will be rejected, your program will pay 20 points to each of the three other players, and for the rest of that round, it will be a "forced tsumogiri" player, which automatically discards every tile it draws and never calls anything.

### Special Rules

There are no special rules such as *dora* or *furiten* in FPM. Any person may complete a hand at any time as long as it is a valid complete hand.

Comment: Sounds fun :) I hope there'll be enough entries to actually play a game though

Answer (score 0):

## Team Gun Battle

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

---

This is an individual competition, where the goal is to be the last player surviving. Fighting always takes place between two teams. At the beginning, every player is randomly assigned to one of two teams and placed randomly on the board.*

Each turn, a player can move north, south, east or west or stay. In addition to moving, they can also shoot a bullet north, south, east, or west. Note that players won't know about other players' movements when they move, but the `shoot()` method is called *after* all moving has taken place. The player can choose to shoot a light bullet, which travels 4 squares per frame and does 1 damage, or a heavy bullet, which travels 2 squares per frame and does 3 damage. The bullets do move on the same step they were shot in, so if a target is less than 4 units away, you can shoot a light bullet without any chance of the target dodging.

Every player has a starting health of 30 and 30 bullets to shoot.

After 1000** or so steps, the round will end. Whichever team has more players alive will be considered the winners. Ties will be broken by whichever team has the highest total health.*** Every player not on the winning team will die, and *the winning team will be split up into two new teams.* This means that half of those who were originally on your side are now your enemies. Another 1000 steps are executed and another winning team is chosen. This process repeats until there is only one player left.

This has some interesting strategic consequences. For example, if your team is winning, it is in your interest to start shooting players on your own team because they may not expect it and you will have to fight them eventually. Similarly, you don't want to waste all of your bullets on the first few rounds <s>because your bullets and your health is not replenished after each round.</s> I like trichoplax's suggestion where ammunition and health could be slightly restored after each round. You want to get your teammates to do as much work as possible before killing them.

The controller almost ready. This is the spec:

```
public class Player1 extends Player {
  public Direction move(World w, int stepsLeft) {
    // stepsLeft = # of steps left in round
    // List of players: w.getPlayers()
    // List of bullets: w.getBullets()
    Player p1 = w.getPlayers().get(0);
    // Check health: p1.getHealth()
    // Check # of bullets left: p1.getBullets()
    // Check team: p1.isOnSameTeam(this)
    // Check position: p1.getPosition()
    return Direction.NORTH; // always move north
  }
  public Bullet shoot(World w, int stepsLeft) {
    // similar to above
    return new Bullet(Direction.NORTH, true); // heavy bullet shot north
  }
}
```

*I think the board should be a square with side length `3*(# of players)`. Hopefully this would make to not too sparsely populated.

**Exact number to be determined. It may be based on the number of players (higher # of players = more steps until the end of the round). 1000 seems like a good number.

*** I'm working on a system that's somewhat more fair. Currently, if there was originally an odd number of players, they were split with one random team getting an extra player. Obviously, that team has a significant advantage under this system. Perhaps it could be percentage of surviving players?

Comment: It *sounds* like it would be easy to forever avoid opponents by just staying off their orthogonal lines. What happens if it never gets down to one player for that reason (or everyone runs out of bullets)?

Comment: @Geobits If everyone runs out of bullets, then I have two options I'm considering: a) Nothing happens, and when the 1000 frames ends at the end of the round, one team is randomly chosen to proceed (that is the default when teams tie exactly; if one team has higher total health than the other, then that team wins) b) everyone's bullets are replenished. Which is better?

Comment: Would it help to give everyone some extra ammunition at the start of each round, but also let them carry over whatever ammunition they saved from the last round?

Comment: If you were feeling mean you could make the arena wrap and have bullets not stop until they hit someone. So dodged bullets will keep looping across the arena, slowly filling it up until there's no way for everyone to avoid them.

Comment: @trichoplax I like your first idea. The second seems like a little harsh since  you have a lot less control of who your bullets hit.

Comment: I did think it might be a little *too* mean :)

Comment: If everyone runs out of bullets, then there is obviously a knife fight.

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes ago, I posted this question as a popularity-contest which was quickly put on hold as too broad. Specifically, the "there are no restrictions on what the programs/functions do" was apparently not quite right.  A commenter also suggested that an empty program would be a possible answer which I knew, but didn't necessarily want to restrict as I think the popularity contest would have taken care of that.  I'd be interested in any suggestions people have to make the question more appropriate for PPCG.

Also, I plan on asking with the tags popularity-contest and restricted-source.  Does that seem right?

Here is the question:

> Inspired by the bonus in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52240/write-code-golf-without-using-any-letters)

Write some code that can be run in multiple directions.  In each direction, the code must be a complete program or a function.  The code must be written in one language (so for example, you **cannot** have a python program that is also a whitespace program when run backwards).

#### Explanation of "multiple directions"

If your code is

```
abcd efgh
 ijklm
nop
```

Then backwards is

```
hgfe dcba
mlkji 
pon
```

And sideways is

```
a n
bio
cjp
dk
 l
em
f
g
h
```

#### Trivial example

Brainfuck

```
 .
.+++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++
 +++++++++.
         .
```

#### Notes

- there are no restrictions on what the functions/programs do
- your code must be able to run in at least two directions, but more is better
- abuse of comments is frowned upon but allowed

Comment: Welcome to the sandbox! You deleted your post before I could add another comment, so here's what I wanted to say: What makes an answer "good" in this question? If we go by the criteria "your code must be able to run in at least two directions, but more is better", which the empty program satisfies, that seems a little contradictory. Thus I think it's good to place some sort of restriction on the programs. I think [tag:source-layout] is better than restricted-source - take a look at the questions there and see what you think :)

Comment: Also, as is even if the question wasn't closed as too broad, it'd probably be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/46932/reading-code-in-8-ways-to-output-8-numbers), which you might want to also take a look at.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through those questions.  And I think you're right.  That other question is pretty similar.  I might just let it go.

Answer (score 0):

#### Allongiator [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

There are a lot of acronyms on the internet -- ROTFL, RTFM, <del>NSA</del>, laser, taser, and so on. Your job is to write code that, given an acronym, can figure out what that acronym might stand for. You'll be given an alphabetically-sorted list of words that you can use, to be provided in the format of your choice.

Note that if you're given an actual acronym, you *don't* have to provide what it really stands for. As an example, given ROTFL, you could output "rolling on the floor laughing", or you could output "rearrange orange thrice free language".

#### Input

1. A dictionary of all of the words you're allowed to use. This is guaranteed to have at least one word for each letter; your program is allowed to do anything it wants if it encounters a letter that it can't find a word for.

   - *Not* necessarily in alphabetical order
   - All in lowercase
2. A string of lowercase letters, with no whitespace, punctuation, or non-letter characters.

They can be given in any format you want. For example, the acronym could be the first command line argument and the dictionary the rest of them, or they could be arguments to a function, or given via standard input, or whatever.

The dictionary contents can be found [here].

#### Output

1. A string containing a space-delimited list of words that form the acronym given as input, from the dictionary given.

   - No trailing whitespace except for a single optional newline
   - The words must be chosen (pseudo-)randomly from the dictionary -- that is, if I run it twice with identical inputs, I should get different outputs<sup>1</sup>.
   - It doesn't have to make sense or be plausible or grammatically correct. Any words that start with the right letters will do; however, bonus points<sup>2</sup> to anyone who manages that.

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins.

All the [standard prohibitions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/31541) apply here, though with the note that accessing the dictionary from the web is acceptable, so long as it's the unmodified dictionary and nothing else.

<sup>1: Barring practically impossible situations.</sup>
<sup>2: That is, a browser cookie</sup>

---

**Sandbox (foot)notes:**

This may very well be a duplicate. I looked around as much as I could, but I don't even know what this is called, so I didn't find much. Apologies if it is.

Would they be acronyms or initialisms? I'm not sure.

I'll add the actual dictionary once I've found a nice one that isn't massive.

Comment: A quick search for acronyms turned up [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22549/acronym-to-phrase)

Comment: @Sp3000 ...I even upvoted that question and I forgot about it. Should I delete this post?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh... might be good to get a second opinion, since I'm not sure whether that one being a popcon changes anything

Comment: @Sp3000 Alrighty. I'll leave this up. (Thanks for replying so quickly, by the way)

Comment: Eww, CR..... =)

Comment: @FarazMasroor Nooo my secret is revealed (I recognize you from that meta question! Hi!)

Answer (score 0):

The 9-hole GOLF challenge

Each of these challenges are [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges to be judged by the GOLF CPU.

### Hole 1: [Prime Partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52489/the-golf-cpu-golfing-challenge-prime-partitions)

### Hole 2: [Sides of a Cuboid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/the-golf-cpu-golfing-challenge-sides-of-a-cuboid)

### Hole 3:

You are given the area of a polygon, and the number of edges of the polygon.  You must find the minimal perimeter of the polygon.  This challenge is more about implementing floating point/decimal numbers efficiently.  Your answer must be accurate to at least 3 decimal places.

```
10, 5:    2.41088
7, 8:     1.20405
6700, 14: 20.9027
```

### Hole 4:

You are given a number, `A`, and a base `B`.  You must take the digits of `A` in base `B` and use each digit as the power of the digits before it.  Assume that integer overflow is desired.  For example,

```
125:  ((5)^2)^1     :25
3234: (((4)^3)^2)^3 :68719476736
18043:              :1
12540:              :0
```

### Hole 5:

We define `F(n)` to be equal to the sum of all previous term's digits, and `F(0) = 1`.  Given `N`, you must return the value of `F(N)`.  This sequence is [A004307](https://oeis.org/A004207) on OEIS

```
0: 1
1: 1
2: 2
3: 4
4: 8
5: 16
6: 23
20: 137
```

### Hole 6:

You must return the `N`th decimal place of [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

```
0:  2
1:  7
5:  8
25: 4
```

### 3 more holes (To come up with)

Do these holes look reasonable?  Enjoyable?  Confusing?

Comment: On hole 2, I think you mean *volume* rather than *area*.

Answer (score 0):

## Gimme your best shot

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

### Introduction

You're fed up. You've tried to sell your car but failed, not knowing whether your price is too high, too low or people are just too picky. Then a programmer decides to take a look at your car and makes you an offer using a program that he had written for judging a car's worth.

### Challenge

Given a car's make, model and mileage, you have to find how much a car is worth using the method below. The shortest program to do so wins.

If the make or model of the car is incorrect, you must output "Error: [input make/model] is invalid".

### Method

First of all, you should scrape all of the prices and mileages of all of the listings on AutoTrader.com of the specified car. Next, plot these on a graph (this graph is not needed to be shown) of mileage against prices.

On the graph you should draw a line of best fit. Now you can read the price on the line of best fit for the specified mileage of the car. Now output this with a dollar sign before the price.

### Example

*None of these prices are correct output*

Ford Fiesta, 200 miles

```
Input: ford, fiesta, 200
Output: $15000
```

Subaru Outback, 0 miles

```
Input: subaru, outback, 0
Output: $27000
```

### Example script

Here's my example test script in Python 2.7 (uses autotrader.co.uk though, not .com):

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, sys, re, pylab

model, make, mileage, postcode = sys.argv[1:]
mileage = int(mileage)

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.autotrader.co.uk/search/used/cars/%s/%s/postcode/%s/"%(model.replace(" ","%20"), make.replace(" ","%20"), postcode)).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

results = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"search-result__content"})

cars = []

for j in results:
    pricetag = j.findAll(text=re.compile(r"&pound;.*"))
    price = int(pricetag[0].replace(',','').replace('&pound;',''))

    mileages = j.findAll(text=re.compile(r".+ miles"))
    mileagecar = int(mileages[1].replace(" miles","").replace(",",""))

    cars.append([mileagecar, price])

x = [k[0] for k in cars]
y = [i[1] for i in cars]

poly = pylab.polyfit(x, y, 2)

print("£"+str(int(pylab.poly1d(poly)(mileage)+0.5)))
```

Comment: I believe scraping autotrader.com violates their visitor agreement. Section 5 seems to imply that it's illegal as well (though that may well depend on the jurisdiction).

Comment: @Geobits Damn it haha... I'll look for some kind of API for another online car sales site...

Comment: I'm also not sure where the pounds/dollars difference comes in. Both of those cars are available in the US, for example, but output is in pounds. I don't see anything in the input to say which to use.

Comment: @Geobits It was based on whether the program used AutoTrader**.com** or **.co.uk**

Comment: Well... I mean I got that. But it's a code golf; why would you use the longer one? I assumed there had to be some *reason* you made the choice, not just because you felt patriotic ;)

Comment: For instance, what if I decide to use the US site, and there are no matches for a particular make/model (even if there may be on the UK site)? Is my output "wrong"?

Comment: @Geobits I see... Well I'll limit it to an American site when/if I find one

Comment: Doesn't really matter where the site is from, really, as long as it's one site. *Or* there's something in the input to determine that. If the input was, say `ford fiesta 200 dollars` (or us/uk, gbp/usd, etc) then that part wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Meta-Manufactoria

Manufactoria is a pretty great programming game.  However, instead of writing machines to solve the problems, **your goal is to write a program that *creates* the machines for you**.  If you are already familiar with Manufactoria, then for the next section, you only need to read the italicized phrases.

## The Rules of Manufactoria

In this version of Manufactoria, *you are placed in a 9x9 world*.  The input generator is in the center top square `(4, 0)`, and the output acceptor is in the center bottom square `(4, 8)`.  When input is generated, it moves immediately down.

Input is represented by a robot that has a queue of colors.  Output will be the same robot, but the queue may contain a different sequence of colors.  *Robots must always eventually end up in the output square.  There are 2 colors available, Red and Blue*.

Each tick, the robot moves 1 square.  The direction the robot moves, and any modifications to the queue is determined by the square it is on.  There are 3 types of squares:

1. Movement square.  This square either moves the robot North, East, South, or West and does not affect the queue.  *You cannot have two movement squares on the same tile*
2. Choice square.   This square moves the robot based on the top color in the queue.  The general Choice square moves the robot east if red, west if blue, south if empty, and never north.  This square can be rotated or reflected to change the directions traveled.
3. Writer square.  This square writes a color to the back of the queue, and moves the robot in a given direction.

## STDIO and Scoring

Your program will be passed two lists of the same length, one containing the inputs, and the other containing the outputs.  Each item of each list contains only the `R` and `B` characters, representing the input queue.

Your output is the board that solves the Manufactoria puzzle.  Each square is represented by two characters.  The first character represents the square type, the second represents the direction.  The square types can be:

- `M`ovement
- `C`hoice
- `R`ed writer
- `B`lue writer.
- `..` Empty square
- `II` Input
- `OO` Output

The directions are:
 - `N`orth
 - `E`ast
 - `S`outh
 - `W`est.

The direction listed for a choice tile represents the direction traveled if the queue is empty.  If the direction is lowercase, the tile is reflected (which swaps the colors).

The program which solves more puzzles than any other program wins.  In the event of a tie, the tiebreaker is the program that produces the most efficient solutions.  Efficiency is measured by the number of times the robot moves across all of the solutions.

Your program should be a general solver.  I may add puzzles to the ones listed below at any time.

## Sample Puzzles

The solutions given below don't necessarily have to do what the title indicates.  Your program's solution also doesn't have to match the ones listed below.  It only needs to solve the inputs given.  The format below is

```
[Inputs] [Outputs]
Solution Map
```

Example 1: Don't do anything

```
["","R","B","RRBR","BRRBRB"] ["","R","B","RRBR","BRRBRB"]

........II........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........OO........
```

[image: Manufactoria 1]

Example 2: Print second `R` and anything after:

```
["","R","B","RR","BRB","RBRBBB"] ["","","","R","","RBBB"]

........II........
..MSCSMWCSMW......
..RSMEMEMS........
BECsMEMEMS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........OO........
```

[image: Manufactoria 2]

Example 3: Reverse String  (This doesn't reverse any string, it only works for the examples listed)

```
["","BBR","B","RRB","BRRRB","BBRB"] ["","RBB","B","BRR","BRRRB","BRBB"]

........IICsMERS..
......CECSCEMSBS..
......RSMSCEMSMW..
......REMSCEMS....
........MSRSMS....
........MSRSMS....
........MSRSMS....
........MSBWMW....
........OO........
```

[image: Manufactoria 3]

Example 4: Only include Rs

```
["R","","BBR","BRR","B","RBRBRBBR","BBBBBBRRR","RBBBRBRBBB","RRRR"] ["R","","R","RR","","RRRR","RRR","RRR","RRRR"]

........II........
........MEMEMEMS..
MSCSMWCSMWCSMWCSMW
REREMERERSMW..MS..
........MSMWMWMW..
........MS........
........MS........
........MS........
........OO........
```

[image: Manufactoria 4]

Comment: Sounds extremely difficult.

Comment: I enjoyed playing that game...Hard indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

(Need a title.)

Write two programs (or functions) in the same language for these two tasks:

1. Given a list of integers, split at every non-negative integer. If there are two or more consecutive non-negative integers, your program should preserve the empty list between them.
2. Given a list of lists of negative integers, concatenate the lists and insert non-negative integers between them. The inserted integer after the *n*th list (zero-based) should be *n*.

Alternatively, you can increment every integer by one for both tasks. So you split at positive integers, accept non-positive integers in task 2 and the inserted integers start at 1.

The input for task 1 and the output for task 2 should have the same format, with the exception that one can be the string representation of the other in your programming language. The same goes for the output for task 1 and the input for task 2.

Your score is the total length of your two programs *times* (30 + their Levenshtein distance). Lowest score wins.

#### Example for task 1

```
Input:  [-5 7 8 -5 2 -6 -3 -3 8]
Output: [[-5] [] [-5] [-6 -3 -3] []]
```

#### Example for task 2

```
Input:  [[-5] [] [-5] [-6 -3 -3] []]
Output: [-5 0 1 -5 2 -6 -3 -3 3]
```

Comment: `if(1>2){code1}else{code2}`. There's no need to ever have the edit distance any greater than 1 or 2.

Comment: better yet: `if(input[0] instanceof Array<int>){code1}else{code2}`. Haskell might be able to pull this off even more cleanly because the typeclasses are resolved at compile time, meaning that even empty arrays have the proper type.

Comment: The first task description is extremely unclear. What does it mean to split? How can one preserve something that didn't exist in the first place?

Comment: @JanDvorak If the answer is less than 30 bytes, it is beneficial to remove a byte while increase the edit distance by one. But maybe I should change it to the length *plus* the edit distance.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It just works like the CJam and GolfScript `/`. I'll try to reword it later if I get the scoring method working.

Answer (score 0):

## Return of the 5318008

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Introduction

A week or so ago, I posted the challenge [5318008](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51871/5318008-fun-with-calculators), with a massive reaction. Now, I want you to do the same again but with musical chords.

### Challenge

Given a word list, you must output a list of words which can be formed using musical chords. However, the word must also sound good too.

The chords which you may use are:

```
A B C D E F G
```

These are all the major chords without the flat/sharp chords.

A word will sound good if all of its letters are within the same key. All the chord progressions which you must concern are listed below:

- **A major**: A D E G
- **B minor**: D G A
- **D major**: D G A
- **E major**: E A B D

Other progressions such as G or C major could not make any word because all of the major chords (which were not sharps or flats) were consonants.

For my tests, I used the UNIX wordlist, gathered by typing:

```
ln -s /usr/dict/words w.txt
```

Or alternatively, get it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt).

There are some uppercase letters in the dictionary, so make all of the letters in all of the words in the dictionary lowercase.

### Winning

The shortest code to output a list of words wins.

Comment: What about A minor?

Comment: @NathanMerrill No vowels in Am, just C F and G

Comment: I don't understand then.  A minor includes "a" and "e"

Comment: What about case sensitivity? Also I'm expecting this to end up as a regex challenge, if I've understood the problem correctly

Comment: @Sp3000 Edited to say that all words should be converted to lowercase

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, I was talking about *chords* instead of *notes* :/

Comment: So I'm to assume that A would only be included if A major is a subset of the key?

Comment: @Nathan Uhh yes

Comment: Ok.  Also, B minor and D major include the same notes, so the notes listed should be the same.  D major shouldn't have the C, as it has a C#.

Comment: I don't know much about music theory, but from what little I do know I find this question very confusing. `A B C D E F G` doesn't look like a list of chords, but like the scale of C major. If by the "*key of C major*" you mean the tonic chord of the scale of C major, that would be `C E G`, which is not all consonants. I also promise to downvote any question which allows people from one specified nation to answer a different question to people from the rest of the world.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Refer to [this](http://www.guitar-chords.org.uk/chords-key-c.html): *The chord chart...lists all the common traids and four note extended chords belonging to the key of C major*.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't clear anything up. Unless... are you sure you're not confusing chords with chord *progressions*?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I didn't know the word for it

Comment: You are definitely confusing notes and chords here. B minor and D major both contain the notes B C# D E F# G A, The possible chords are Bm Em F#m Dmaj Gmaj Amaj and C#dim, with F#m and Em often subsituted for Fmaj and Emaj. One valid interepretation is that both keys contain all these chords, another is that the minor is just B E (F#) and the major is just D G A. Under no circumstance can Bm be considered D G A. You are also misusing the word progression. This refers to the sequence of chords in a particular song and has nothing to do with the chords available in a particular key.

Comment: A major contains A B C# D E F# G# so the only natural notes are ABDE,which is what you have written for E major. E major contains one additional sharp E F# G# A B C# D# so the only natural notes are E A B.

Answer (score 0):

## VSEPR Strikes Back!

(Note: I know that the VSEPR method fails sometimes, and that there are exceptional molecules. This is addressed in the scoring system, and otherwise the challenge is about the molecules which conform.)

Most people who have taken an introductory chemistry course know about molecules, and (probably) the [VSEPR theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) of chemical bonding. Basically, the theory predicts the shape of a molecule given three main properties: the central atom A, the number of atoms bonded to *the central atom* X, and the number of lone electron pairs E on the central atom. Applying the VSEPR theory is simply a matter of finding the values of X and E (A always has an implied value of 1, as we'll see). This is called the AXE method. For example, a molecule which has 1 lone pair and 3 atoms bonded to the main atom is AX<sub>3</sub>E<sub>1</sub>, which is the [trigonal pyramidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_pyramidal_molecular_geometry) configuration.

### The Challenge

Your job is, given a covalent chemical compound, to output the geometrical shape of the molecule inputted. *But wait!* exclaim the exasperated programmers, *you can't expect us to input all of the molecular data for every element!* Of course we can, but I'm not feeling particularly masochistic today, so born was the scoring system below.

The input is any molecule, such as `CO2` or `HgCl2`, and the output should be the name of the shape and NOT the AXE form. Ions should have their charge put in parenthesis directly after the ion, such as CO3(2-) or NH4(1+). 1- and - (and 1+ and +) are all acceptable.

### About the central atom A

In most cases, the central atom will be apparent. It usually has no subscript in the chemical formula: the C in `CO`<sub>`2`</sub> is the central atom, for example. In a few cases, though, you might face compounds like [ethelyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene) (C<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub>), in which no clear atom is the central one. In this case, it is worth noting that such compounds are usually symmetrical, and considering any carbon to be the central atom will do.

### Scoring System

The base score is the number of bytes the program takes.

1. There is a minimum of 6 elements to be implemented for input; every 5 extra you add multiplies your score by 0.9.
2. Multiply your score by 0.8 if you can make your code work for ions.
3. Multiply your score by 0.9 if you can detect ionic compounds (VSEPR only works for covalent compounds) and reject them accordingly.
4. Multiply your score by 0.8 if you also output the bond angles.
5. There are certain classes of molecules which VSEPR fails to predict correctly, due to various reasons. (Check the first link in the post for the section on the exceptions.) Multiply your code by 0.9 per class if it returns those correctly.

### Test Cases

The parts in brackets are optional bonuses from above.

> CO<sub>2</sub>: CO2 -> linear [180*]
>   HgCl<sub>2</sub>: HgCl2 -> linear [180*]
>   H<sub>2</sub>O: H2O -> bent [104.5*]
>   [CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>: CO3(2-) -> trigonal planar 120*]
>   BrF: BrF<sub>3</sub> -> T-shaped [90*]
>   [NaCl: NaCl -> Ionic compound]
>   XeF<sub>4</sub>: XeF4 -> square planar [90*]

Notes:
 - The bonding patterns are not valid when the central atom is a transition metal (so don't do that.).
 - Standard loopholes apply.

Answer (score 0):

## Live Tennis Scoreboard

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In this challenge, we're going to create a tennis scoreboard that could (theoretically) be used in an actual tennis match. The tennis scoreboard will display the score while listening on STDIN. As new results come in on STDIN, the tennis scoreboard will update itself accordingly.

#### Description of Input

When the scoreboard is first instantiated, it will be provided input for two strings -- these are the names of the competitors. This can be via command line arguments, user input functions, etc.

After that, the scoreboard will recieve input via STDIN. These correspond to events that the scoreboard should reflect in the score.

- `0`

  The first player has scored a point.
- `1`

  The second player has scored a point.
- `U`

  Undo the previous point and revert to the previous state of the scoreboard.

The scoreboard must handle games, deuces, etc. as described in the next section.

#### Terse Description of Tennis Scoring System

This section here describes the exact rule set to use.

A *match* is between two players. To win a match, a player must win three *sets*. To win a set, a player must win at least six *games* and have a two-game lead over their opponent. To win a game, a player must win at least four *points* and have a two-point lead over their opponent.

The number of sets and games won are displayed as is. Points are displayed as follows in order of priority:

- 1 point = `15`
- 2 points = `30`
- 3 points = `40`
- Number of points won are equal to the opponent = `40`
- Number of points won are one greater than the opponent = `Ad`

Tiebreaks are optional. Implementing tiebreaks grants you **-40** to your score.

#### Scoreboard Format

During the first set and first game:

```
Name | x
Name | x
```

where `x` is the point display for each player.

During the first set:

```
Name a | x
Name a | x
```

where `a` is the number of games won by each player.

During the second set:

```
Name b a | x
Name b a | x
```

where `b` is the result of the first set.

During the third set:

```
Name c b a | x
Name c b a | x
```

where `c` is the result of the second set.

etc. for fourth and fifth sets.

Example:

```
Federer 5 6 6 3 2 | 0
Murray  7 4 4 6 2 | 15
```

Comment: A bit of a far stretch, but it would be cool if you could point the programs at URL which gave the scores for an actual tennis match

Answer (score 0):

## Punch buggy?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

As some of you might know, "punch buggy" is a children's(?) game that involves spotting Volkswagen Beetles and punishing other players. For reference, the car on the left is a punch buggy, while the car on the right is not:

[image: punch-buggy-yellow][image: not-punch-buggy]

Your task is: given an image, determine whether there is a punch buggy shown in it. Entries will be scored by percent correct among all *n* (TBD) test images. If there is a tie, it will be broken by run time on my computer (specs will be posted on main).

Test images may contain just about anything, and come in various sizes. Most will be automobiles of various types, but I will make sure they have a maximum of one auto in them (so if you see a non-matching car, you don't need to look for more). I won't use toy cars or heavily modified cars to try to fool you. Images will be pulled from Google Image Search, and will be of varying quality (from ad-quality to candid in-the-yard).

**This is not a Kolmogorov complexity challenge.** The point is not to recognize specific image files, but to recognize a Beetle in any picture. If it looks like someone is cheating this, I will change to a different test set and re-score.

#### Spec

Input is the name of an image file in JPG or PNG format (should I restrict this to one?).

Output is `Punch Buggy!` if a punch buggy is present in the picture, and any other non-empty string if not.

Programs are run once per image. I will write a simple test controller for this using STDIO, so programs must be runnable from the command line, using a language that is freely available on Ubuntu.

You are allowed to read/write other files, but only in a folder with the relative path `/yourProgramName`. You are allowed to *read* files  whose names are passed as input via STDIN.

#### Test Images

(will include link to collection when posted, probably about 100 total)

#### Sandbox

Yes, this seems a bit difficult to me, too. I don't see that as a problem. Is there anything that isn't clear about the task or spec? Other notes/questions/suggestions?

If it needs fluff (I'm not sure yet), it will probably be something like "help my robot become more human via children's games".

Comment: Personally, I don't think this is that hard. You just look for a large grouping of yellow pixels around the centre of the image. I think you should limit it to a PNG.

Comment: @BetaDecay That would only work if all punch buggies are yellow and all other images/cars are not. The images shown here are only representative samples. The test cases will include various cars of various colors at various angles in various lighting conditions.

Comment: Ohh I thought Punch Buggy was when you have a yellow car, not just a Beetle

Comment: Ah. That's the [Yellow Car Game](http://www.yellowcargame.co.uk/pages/officialrules.htm). Similar, but yea, that would be a different difficulty level.

Comment: I afraid even if you people try to recognize buggies their results will come from randomness and overlearning on the provided images. Recognizing a car at all would be a difficult task itself.

Comment: If you want to avoid this being a kolmorogov challenge, would it help to provide a much larger training set and test on a small subset of this that is not announced in advance? That does introduce a deadline excluding future submissions though.

Comment: @trichoplax Not necessarily, because you could always test the new submissions using the subset (which is still unannounced)

Comment: @BetaDecay good point. That makes this sort of challenge seem much more promising.

Comment: @trichoplax Though it could still be a kolmogorov complexity because a program could be programmed to recognise all pictures in the album, and choosing a subset wouldn't stop that program from getting full marks

Answer (score 0):

## Clarence the Fast? Typist

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(Inspired by this [excellent question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50722/clarence-the-slow-typist#comment120076_50722) on the original challenge.)

**Introduction**

Lawrence is a business manager who works at an Internet service provider. Recently, he has noticed that Clarence, the data entry clerk, has been [typing a little slow lately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50722/21682). Since Clarence's job is entering the IP addresses manually into the database, Lawrence is starting to get worried. *Especially* that there is now a backlog of angry customers who are calling to ask why they are not connected to the Internet yet.

Lawrence, as you might expect from one who manages an ISP, has hit upon what he considers to be an excellent solution to the problem. He decides to optimise the layout of Clarence's keypad to make it faster for him to type in the IP addresses.

Clarence's keypad is normally laid out as follows:

<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`3`</kbd>
<kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd><kbd>`6`</kbd>
<kbd>`7`</kbd><kbd>`8`</kbd><kbd>`9`</kbd>
<kbd>`.`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`E`</kbd> (E stands for "Enter")

The distance between the centres of each adjacent key is 1 centimetre. Clarence types using the "eagle search" system -- he uses one finger only and moves that finger from key to key to type in an address. For example, to input the number `7851`, Clarence would start his finger on <kbd>7</kbd>, move 1cm right to <kbd>8</kbd>, move 1cm up to <kbd>5</kbd>, then move √2cm to <kbd>1</kbd> -- a total of 3.41cm.

If we rearrange his keypad like this, we can get better results:

<kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`3`</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd><kbd>`6`</kbd>
<kbd>`7`</kbd><kbd>`8`</kbd><kbd>`9`</kbd>
<kbd>`.`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`E`</kbd>

With this layout Clarence only needs to move his finger 3cm. This saves time!

Your task is to write a program that determines the most optimal keypad layout, given a list of IP addresses that Clarence must type in. Clarence needs to push the <kbd>E</kbd> after each IP address, so you also need to optimise the position of the <kbd>E</kbd> key.

**Input Description**

Input is a newline separated list of IP addresses. Each IP address is a string that will be in the form

`().().().()`

where each `()` is an integer in the range `0` - `999`. I would also like to point out that addresses such as `0.42.42.42` or `999.999.999.999` in the input are still valid, despite the fact that they are invalid IP addresses. So you don't need to include any IP address verification code in your program.

**Output Description**

Output the layout of the keys such that the distance Clarence needs to move his finger to type them all in is as low as possible. If there are multiple layouts that are equally as low, output any one of them.

The format for the output looks like this:

```
123
456
789
.0E
```

[todo: example inputs and outputs]

Comment: Lose the intentional confusion of the names. The point of a specification is to be easily understood, not deliberately confusing.

Comment: I don't think it affects the challenge in any way, but `999.999.999.999` makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0):

## Kolmorogov image complexity

[kolmorogov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmorogov-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

---

The 512 by 512 pixel image below [ *to be added when posting to main* ] was produced using a combination of simple methods that, if known, would allow reproducing the image with a short program. It is therefore known to have low Kolmorogov complexity. However, the original methods used will not be revealed. Instead your challenge is to produce code that outputs this image by your own best method, pixel perfect, so that the hash of your image matches the hash of this image.

[image: Blank image to show size 512 by 512 pixels]

[ *Hash* ]

You may use any built ins and libraries that existed publicly before the challenge was posted, including graphical libraries.

### Input and output

#### Input

- Your code is not required to take input.
- Your code must be able to produce the correct output without taking input.

#### Output

You may use any freely available image format (free and free) or display the image to screen. Your code is not responsible for converting the image to a format that can be hashed for validation.

### Winning

A valid answer is one for which the output passes the validation test. The winner is the valid answer with the shortest code in bytes.

### Validator

The following code takes a PNG image as input and outputs a hash of its pixel values, announcing whether this is valid.

[ *Validator to be added later* ]

---

## Sandbox questions

- ***I'm considering posting a few example images here in the sandbox so people can feedback on which one would make the best candidate for posting to main. Is this acceptable if I keep the time between posting example images and posting to main reasonably short (a day or two)?***
- Would it be better to approach this from the opposite direction and say the winner is the closest to the target image in 300 bytes? I think it can work as a question with insisting on an exact match though - I'm aiming to have several aspects to be golfed down, so even if not all are golfed well the total length should still be manageable. I prefer an exact match and open ended code length, as a byte limit has very different effects on different languages.
- Is there any general advice on what to remember/avoid when preparing the target image? Obviously this cannot be very specific advice as the exact method will not be discussed before posting to main. However, I welcome any hints at things that would make for a good challenge and things that would be trivial or too difficult. **I'm definitely going to follow Peter Taylor's advice and avoid any crypto or Mandelbrot zooms. The image should be fairly easy to identify, so the emphasis can be on golfing down the components rather than solving a mystery.**
- Would it be better to say "the original method will never be revealed" or "the original method will be revealed once an answer is posted that is shorter than it" or "the original method will be revealed after a set time period"? The last one is my least favourite. I like the idea of a challenge being open ended, so I would prefer to reveal at most only what is already beaten by existing answers.
- I like the idea of using patterns that will be recognisable so people can say "I know that pattern from somewhere" and then look it up and tweak the parameters, rather than just presenting a random looking image that happens to have a simple description. Does this sound like an interesting challenge?

Comment: This basically looks like a single-robber cops-and-robbers. In particular, the by now well-known issues around use of crypto in robbers should be taken into account. Guess-the-Mandlebrot-parameters is also likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24909/kolmogorov-mania . This got very mixed votes at first. Note the edit made with the clue. I say pick an image and try it. Don't say the oiginal method will *never* be revealed, just give more hints until someone gets it.

Comment: @steveverrill I definitely don't want something as obscured as that - I want the pattern to be perfectly visible so it's more about golfing than guessing. I like the idea of gradual hints, but if I get mine how I'm aiming to, it won't need hints, just golfing.

Answer (score 0):

## Is a picture worth a thousand words?

There is an old saying that goes "A picture is worth a thousand words".
For us programmers, pictures and words are actually quantifiable in bytes.
(A word is worth `8` bytes on a standard 64-bit system, a thousand words is worth `8000` bytes, and an image is worth the number of bytes needed to store it in the particular format it is in.)

Write a program or function that, given the path of an image as input, determines if it is or is not worth a thousand words. Print `worth it` if it is, and `not worth it` if it is not.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest answer wins!

### Problems:

Too simple, maybe have the programs perform a check on the environment to determine actual word length?

No test cases (Yet)

Question is sort of short

Comment: I _love_ the title, but I'd agree the challenge is too simple. This is just `os.path.getsize` in Python, for instance. I'd suggest playing off the 'thousand words' part of the challenge more.

Comment: @Pyrrha how would you suggest playing off of the 'thousand words' part? A thousand literal english words? Maybe have the program convert an image into words and words into images (Obviously not accurately, e.g. 'Blue' will not give a blue image, 'Blue' is just a symbol. 1000 symbols represent the image by dictionary lookup, or something.

Comment: If you have a good idea feel free to take over the challenge :)

Comment: Alternative: Find 1000 English words (i.e. letter sequences) in the image file’s source code.

Answer (score 0):

### Write an Adblocker!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Introduction

You've gotten tired of reading text ads dispersed throughout your content.
You've tried solving this problem using a simple find-and-replace solution, but the advertisers have wisened up!
Every text ad now comes in slightly different variations to slip past your filter.

#### Challenge

Write an adblocker that, given a sample ad, removes all variations of it from the content.
Your program must remove every sentence in the input for which 75% of its words are identical, and in the same location.

This is codegolf, shortest answer in bytes wins!

#### Example

Given an example sentence from an advertisement, such as

`Buy my computer now with cheap free shipping.`

`Buy my laptop today with cheap free shipping.`

is an ad because 6 out of 8 words (>= 75%) are identical and in the same locations.

`The computer was expensive but shipping was free.`

is not an ad because 0 out of 8 words (< 75%) are identical and in the same location.
Note how `computer`, `shipping`, and `free` don't count as identical because they are in different positions in the sentence.

If a sentence is not the same length as the ad, it isn't an ad.

#### Bonus

After matching an ad, remember which words were used as replacements, and use them to match future ads.

For example, when `Buy my laptop today with cheap free shipping.` was matched to the given sample `Buy my computer now with cheap free shipping.`, your program should remember that `laptop` and `today` are synonyms for `computer` and `now`, respectively.

If `laptop` or `today` are ever encountered in a future sentence, they should be matched with their synonyms in the ad.

Your program only needs to match synonyms in content that appears after the synonym was found.

So, if the sentence `Purchase my laptop today with cheap free shipping.` was encountered after your program found out about the aforementioned synonyms, it would match because 7 out of 8 words matched in the same location (>= 75%). Note that a program that doesn't claim the bonus would only match 5 out of 8 words (< 75%), and would not consider the sentence an ad.

Your program should then proceed to make note that `Purchase` is a synonym for `Buy`, and continue processing the content.

**Programs claiming this bonus can claim a 35% reduction of their score, i.e. `score_with_bonus = number_of_bytes * 0.65`.**

#### Input

Accept one sentence as a sample advertisement followed by a number of sentences of content.
Only letters of the alphabet, spaces, and periods will appear in the input.

Input may be taken in any convenient format for your language. For example, accepting a string for the ad sentence and an array of strings for the content is acceptable.

#### Output

Output the content without the ad variations.
The content must be in the same order.

The output may come in any reasonable format for your language. For example, printing to a file or stdout is acceptable. If your language makes it easier to output an array like `["Content 1", "Content 2", ...]`, or in a similar such format, this is acceptable.

#### Test Cases

***Input***

```
Two for one deal on lumber for a limited time only.
    
Make sure to pace yourself well when you run long distances.
You don't want to tire too quickly.
Three for one deal on tires for a limited time only.
Training is a must.
Two for one deal on lumber for a limited time only.
Three for one deal on tires for a short period only.
```

***Output*** (with bonus)

```
Make sure to pace yourself well when you run long distances.
You don't want to tire too quickly.
Training is a must.
```

***Output*** (no bonus)

```
Make sure to pace yourself well when you run long distances.
You don't want to tire too quickly.
Training is a must.
Three for one deal on tires for a short period only.
```

#### Notes

You may write a program or function.

More test cases to come!

*This is my first challenge, so please give suggestions on how to improve!*

*In particular, comments on whether or not the bonus is appropriate would be appreciated. Also, it would be nice to know thoughts concerning the challenge as a whole (good, bad, too easy, too hard...?), so that I can better frame future ideas!*
*Thanks!*

Comment: So the input won't have any newlines? That is, the content will be a series of one or more sentences just separated by a period and a space? Could I write a function that accepts the ad as one parameter and the content as another?

Comment: You many accept the input in any reasonable format. (So yes, @AlexA., that would be fine)

Comment: But what about `So buy my computer now, cheap with shipping`? That's just 1 out of 8, when in reality it should be 7 out of 8...

Comment: You mention that commas may be included in the input, but you don't say how they affect the matching.

Comment: @BetaDecay For the purposes of the challenge, we assume that the advertisers do not get more sophisticated than a simple replacement of words, not an addition, subtraction, or rearrangement of words. Obviously this wouldn't be a very effective adblocker, but I thought it would make for a reasonable challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Commas may be ignored in the input. Periods only matter for separating sentences. For matching purposes, only letters of the alphabet matter.

Comment: If commas can be ignored, you might as well remove them entirely from the spec. `',-` (in CJam) isn't really where the interest lies.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, commas aren't where the interest lies. I'll remove them from the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

(Possible deadlines?)

## The robber and the bank (Bank managers)

### (Based off 'Two makes all the difference')

A group of robbers has decided to break into a bank, but one of the members leaked the information to the bank. To stop the robbers from getting any money, they have decided to change the combination on each vault to something more complicated.

### Your task

As you are a bank manager, you must figure out a new combination of rotations for the wheel lock system of the vaults. The vaults take 7 turns each, represented in degrees. You must write a program that takes 10 integers (separated in any way you like) and outputs the processed integers **which have been made from the originals.** This is important, as you cannot use a randomizing function to make the new combination.

#### Sample input:

(Note: The numbers will all be multiples of 5. The output should also be this way.)

`10, 50, -230, 110, 20, -5, 50, 80, 30, -50`

#### Sample output:

`30, 110, -110, 230, 50, 115, 110, 170, 70, 70`

This result is obtained by the simple (Python 3) algorithm (deliberately non-golfed)

```
inputlist = input('list')
for i in len(inputlist):
    if inputlist(i) > 0:
        inputlist(i) *= 2
        inputlist(i) += 10
    else:
        inputlist(i) += 120
```

(Note the abscence of a condition for 0 degrees, as a wheel lock would not take such a value. Also note the fact that the algorithm is a full program, not just a function that would do the same.)

### Winning conditions

The shortest uncracked algorithm wins. In case there are two algorithms that have the same length and are uncracked, the one with more votes will win.

## The robber and the bank (Robbers)

Your group of robbers are breaking into a bank! However, one of your members seems to have leaked the information to the bank managers. Your team manages to hack the bank's system to retrieve the original password and part of the algorithm, but your connection was cut.

### Your task

You will receive 10 integers and a snippet of code (need help deciding how much) from the algorithm used to change the lock's combination. You will need to deduce what the algorithm is and finally the new combination.

#### Sample information:

`10, 50, -230, 110, 20, -5, 50, 80, 30, -50`
`Part of code`

#### Sample answer:

`30, 110, -110, 230, 50, 115, 110, 170, 70, 70`
`Code (optional)`

### Winning conditions

The robber with the most vaults (algorithms/combinations) cracked wins. In the case that there are two robbers with the same number of cracked vaults, the robber with more votes will win.

(Any way to separate who wants to be a robber and who wants to be a manager? Perhaps a separate system for answering?)

Comment: 1. It's quite confusing the way you keep talking about algorithms when you mean programs. 2. It's not at all clear what exactly the bank managers post. 3. It's not at all clear that the robbers can do anything except guess.

Answer (score 0):

**SETI (search for extraterrestrial life)**

In this code golf challenge you will search for signs of life.

Specification:

Your program takes a sequence of exactly 225 characters, each either 0 or 1. You return as output a single bit, either 0 or 1.

The goal is to distinguish between two kinds of inputs:

0 (no extraterrestrial life): Each character is zero or one independently at random, and is one with probability exactly 15%.

1 (extraterrestrial life): First, each character is zero or one independently at random, and is one with probability exactly 28%. Then, 10 rounds of the original Conway's Game of Life are played from this configuration. The 225 characters are viewed as a 15 by 15 grid, and when we apply the rules, we treat the grid as wrapping around so that it has no borders. That is, column 1 wraps around and is adjacent to column 15, and row 1 also wraps around and is adjacent to row 15. The symbol '0' is associated with 'dead' and the symbol '1' is associated with alive. After the 10 rounds the string corresponding to the state of the game is the input.

Your program does not need to give any particular output for any particular input, however it should succeed on average in the following sense. If we flip a fair coin (either 0 or 1), and choose an input from the corresponding distribution, your program should output the correct answer with probability at least 90%.

Otherwise this is code golf as usual. Enjoy!

I/O:

Your program shall accept as input a sequence of 225 characters, each either 0 or 1. You may request in your answer that the characters are space-delimited, comma-delimited, or not delimited. You may request in your answer that the input is given on standard in, or, if your answer is a program which takes command-line arguments, you may assume that the characters are passed on the command-line so that each character is an argument (assuming your shell supports passing 225 arguments to a program), or, if your language supports the concept of "global variables / values", you may write your program under the assumption that a known global variable, of the simplest "character sequence" type that your language supports, contains the input.

Your answer shall output a single bit either zero or one. You shall do this either by printing the character 0 or 1 to standard out, or by returning an integer value 0 or 1 from a designated "main" function.

Comment: This question is going to need a fair number of test cases, soo that people can tell if their program works. Maybe a test case generator?

Comment: I guess I assumed people would just write their own test case generator in their language of choice. I wrote one here in C++, that's what I used to pick the parameters http://hastebin.com/uguhapepat.avrasm

Comment: added a license statement http://hastebin.com/sevimunolu.avrasm

Comment: 8 rounds or 10 rounds?

Comment: Humm you know i'm open to suggestions, but I originally had 8 and then I made the board smaller and increased it to 10, I guess I left an 8 in there though. i'm going to edit to make it 10 everywhere

Comment: So my goals for setting the parameters were like: (1) I thought there should still be some significant amount of noise in the life game, it shouldn't have enough time to entirely settle down into squares and flippers (2) I want you to have to do something more complex than "just count the number of 1's". If the same percentage is used for the random ones in both the "yes" and "no" instances, it leads to a large gap in density of ones because life tends to kill off many of the 1s after you start from random. so i made the board small and tuned the %s so that counting ones gives little info.

Answer (score 0):

## Infinite monkeys and a broken keyboard

The [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) describes the probability of getting the desired result by just doing random stuff.

The task of this challenge is to calculate the minimum number of monkeys you need to get a given text on a broken keyboard.
The situation is easy:

- You have a keyboard (QWERTY-layout) that has lost some of its keys
- Possible keys are: `1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -=\[];',./`
- Only one button is pressed at a time and the other keys (enter, tab, numeric keypad, ...) will not be pressed/ are already lost
- You have many many many monkeys which want to type on the keyboard!

### Input

The input is a string which can only contain the possible chars. You may assume that **only** the characters that are in the given string aren't lost.

### Task

You have to calculate how many monkeys are at least necessary to get the given input with a probability of **over 50%**. Afterwards just output that number.

### Examples

```
input: aaaa
    1 key available -> P=100% to hit the right key
output: 1

input: abcd
    4 keys available -> P=25% to hit the right key
    Probability to get the desired string:
    P = 25%^4 = 0.00390625
    Number n of monkeys needed:
    (1-0.00390625)^n < 50%
    n = 178 (P=50.176%)
output: 178
```

Please tell me if you have ideas how to improve or clarify the question or how to optimize it.

Comment: [Similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40745/monkeys-at-a-typewriter), but I think this is a better question than mine

Answer (score 0):

## Alternating Hamiltonian Chess Boards

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

---

### Overview

**Find a Hamiltonian cycle on a chess board that alternates between black and white squares. The catch is that the board does not have the colours arranged in the conventional way.**

---

### Detail

Consider a chess board, with each square having 4 neighbours (up, down, left, right), apart from the edge and corner squares which only have 3 or 2 neighbours respectively. A [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is a closed path (loop) that visits every square exactly once, moving from neighbour to neighbour (never diagonally).

On a chess board, it is easy to find a Hamiltonian cycle that alternates between black and white squares (in fact, *any* cycle will alternate between black and white squares). What if the black and white squares were not arranged so conveniently? Clearly there are arrangements for which there is no possible alternating Hamiltonian cycle, for example putting all the white squares in one half of the board.

The task of your code is to find any valid cycle, or indicate if there are none.

### Input & output

#### Input

An 8 by 8 board of black and white squares.

This is in the form of a string of 64 characters each of which is either "0" or "1", terminated by a newline. This indicates the colours of the squares in English reading order.

#### Output

Any valid cycle if one exists, or a zero as an indication that no valid cycle exists.

A cycle is represented by a comma separated list of integers from 0 to 63 inclusive, indicating the order in which the squares are visited. Again the labelling is in English reading order.

Whether a list of a zero, the output is terminated with a newline.

### Square numbering

The squares are labelled in English reading order (left to right then top to bottom). So for example, a 3 by 3 board would be labelled as follows:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is this equivalent to another question already asked?
- My first thought was [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but I'm now preferring [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code). There are a number of quick checks that can eliminate the possibility of there being a valid cycle, which will be competitive in fastest code. I'd rather see these than golfed brute force approaches.
- I've chosen 8 by 8 simply because it's a familiar size due to chess. Would this be better with a different size board? For fastest code I'd want the time taken to be over a minute for at least some inputs, so that there is enough time to judge the difference between answers. Ideally for fastest code I'd choose inputs that take quite a bit longer than that to allow for solutions which are far more efficient than I expect.
- How restrictive should I be with the input and output formats? For fastest code if the body of the problem takes a reasonably long time then input and output conversion should be negligible so I could insist on a single format for ease of measuring answers.
- Is there any advantage to having a fixed board size, or would it be more interesting with the board size as an initial input N, followed by the board?

Comment: i think "fastest code" is most interesting b/c with code golf its just going to boil down to who can write the shortest exhaustive guess & check program. for fastest code I guess probably that there is some efficient algorithm for hamilton cycles on bipartite graphs? but i'm not actually sure, probably there would be alot of tricks to solve this quickly, and maybe exploit planarity somehow.

Comment: @ChrisBeck the more I think about it the more I'm leaning towards fastest code too. In which case I'll include unsolvable boards in the input cases too. That will really separate the brute force solutions from those that have clever ways to fail fast.

Comment: @ChrisBeck and trichoplax - I'm intrigued but skeptical. Checking for Hamiltonian cycles is NP-Complete. If we think of the input as a graph with vertices representing the white squares and edges representing the black squares, this easily translates into many algorithms that ask about Hamiltonian paths. Presuming an even split between white and black squares, this results in a maximum of 32! different possible paths to brute force check, or, in the best Monte Carlo simulations, O(1.657^32). That's still 17+ minutes if your algorithm can check 10,000 possible paths per second.

Comment: It might not be NP-complete when restricted to graphs like this though. I'm not sure, my hunch is no, maybe you see a reduction though? Regardless I'm quite sure that it will be at most like, exponential in the number of rows here, not like exponential in the number of grid squares. (Because, it can be translated to a SAT instance of bounded tree-width and there are known algorithms for those.) Making the graph bipartite is often a pretty severe restriction that dramatically reduces the complexity as well.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Hence why I said I'm intrigued but skeptical. I haven't gone through anything rigorous - the "white squares as nodes and black squares as edges" was just something immediate that sprang to mind. It's certainly possible that there are enough restrictions on the input that can dramatically reduce complexity -- at the least, think of my ruminations as quantifying a maxima.

Comment: @TimmyD If 17 minutes is the worst case brute force then I'll probably increase the size of the board. There are several methods of spotting certain classes of unsolvable boards almost instantly so I'm hoping for solutions that exit very early where possible, and are also optimised with a good heuristic for spotting the solutions that do exist.

Comment: I definitely want to give this plenty of thought before settling on a board size (or maximum test size if I settle on having board size as an input).

Comment: @TimmyD I'm interested in your O(1.657^32). Does that assume anything about the number of neighbours per square?

Comment: @TimmyD I'm fairly sure this case is simpler than the 32! you describe, as each black square has a maximum of 4 white squares to choose from, and some have less otherwise finding a cycle becomes trivial.

Comment: Brute-force checking an n-node graph for a Hamiltonian cycle is O(n!) - that's just straight math, regardless of any bounds on edge connectivity. Way too big to try. "Simple" algorithms exist to check in O(2^n) time, and have been known for years. I've not read the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0541) showing O(1.657^n) time, so I can't comment specifically, but I would imagine that the author tackles the general case, since they explicitly call out bipartite graphs as being solvable in O(1.414^n) ... I _think_ that's the current best-case. My "17-minute" remark was for the O(1.657^n) time.

Comment: That all said, I do believe that there are ways to shrink that O(1.657^32) time, given the constraints present (i.e., each vertex will have a maximum of 4 edges). I'd have to spend some more time thinking about this than I have to determine for sure. Additionally, all this is assuming that my mapping of "white squares as vertices, black squares as edges" is optimal, which I'm much too humble to think is the case, so there could be different ways of optimizing that, too.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/dennis-doorknob-martin-b%c3%bcttner-chris-jester-young-pizzeria), in a general sense. Might be worthwhile to watch what happens with that one, just to see reaction and responses.

Comment: @TimmyD Thanks - it will be interesting to see if the answers there turn out to be convertible to answers here.

Comment: I know that this is ancient history now, but I'm fairly positive you *can't* construct a Hamiltonian path if the squares aren't checkered.  Simple proof:  Assuming a standard checkerboard, and that you start on black, there's no way to get to another black without taking 2N steps, and white without taking 2N-1 steps.  If you swap a black with a white, then you will never be able to step on the black square on a 2N step.

Comment: @NathanMerrill thanks for the proof. It does seem that this challenge will only be possible if I allow diagonal steps in the path too. I should have started by making some test cases. I have some more thinking to do...

Answer (score 0):

### Buffalo buffalo buffallo buffalo buffallo buffallo buffallo parse buffalo buffalo buffallo buffalo buffallo buffallo buffallo

Write a program that can take a integer input N > 0 and then describes the syntax of a phrase in the style of "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo" with N repetitions.

[The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) has the parse tree and accepted syntax for phrases up to N = 8.

> The sentence is unpunctuated and uses three different readings of the word "buffalo". In order of their first use, these are:
>
> - a. the city of Buffalo, New York, United States, which is used as a noun adjunct in the sentence and is followed by the animal;
> - n. the noun buffalo, an animal, in the plural (equivalent to "buffaloes" or "buffalos"), in order to avoid articles;
> - v. the verb "buffalo" meaning to outwit, confuse, deceive, or intimidate.

So for the first eight the output should be:

> 1. Bully (meaning the imperative "[you] Buffalo!" - command someone to bully).
> 2. NY bison (meaning a bison that hails from the town of Buffalo).
> 3. NY bison bully (a bison from NY bullies).
> 4. NY bison bully bison (NY Bison bully a bison)
> 5. NY bison bully NY bison (NY bison bully NY bison)
> 6. Buffalo buffalo buffallo buffalo buffallo buffallo (NY bison bully **(TBC)**
> 7. Buffalo buffalo buffallo buffalo buffallo buffallo
> 8. Buffalo buffalo buffallo buffalo buffallo buffallo buffallo

In the comments section, wikipedian Robin Johnson has it for 9 through 12 (NY stands for Buffalo, NY):

> 9. (NY bison [which] bison bully) bully (bison [which] NY bison bully)
> 10. (Bison) bully (NY bison [which] NY bison (NY bison bully) bully)
> 11. (NY Bison) bully (NY bison [which] NY bison ([which] NY bison bully) bully)
> 12. (bison [which] bison ([which] NY bison bully) bully) bully (NY bison [which] NY bison bully)

He added parenthesis for more phrase visibility, but that is not needed.

Your program should take the input and explain the gramatically correct phrase doing the following substitutions:

- NY for the Buffalo, NY city.
- Bison for the animal Buffalo.
- Bully for the verb.

[code-golf] [kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: Are we allowed to use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org)?

Comment: The name is a little obnoxious to be honest. I would recommend removing at least a few "buffalos" from either side of "parse."

Comment: @AlexA. that is a good suggestion, and I think the title as is is gramatically wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

## Get home by ONLY turning right

You're finally trying to get a drivers license. About halfway during the lesson, the instructor decides that you've sufficiently mastered telling the gas- and brake pedal apart. It's time to practice the next thing: turning right.

### The challenge

Your program is provided an ASCII roadmap, with your starting position, direction and home marked. You should drive home in the minimum distance required.

Your program must output route instructions for reaching your destination. The following instructions must be printed by your program whenever appropriate.

#### Input

Items on the map will look like this. There are only horizontal and vertical roads. *(I'm open for suggestions on this one.)*

- `=` – A horizontal road
- `|` – A vertical road
- `#` – A crossroad
- `>` / `<` / `^` / `v` – A one-way street
- `H` – Your home
- `N` / `E` / `S` / `W` – Your starting point and direction (`N`orth, `E`ast etc. The  map is oriented north-up.)

A road segment (a signle character) is connected to another segment when:

1. It ends at an adjacent segment that has the same alignment. E.g.: `==` or

   ```
   |
   |
   ```
2. It ends at a segment with a different alignment (horizontal vs vertical). E.g.: `=|`, `|=`,

   ```
   =
   |
   ```

   or

   ```
   |
   =
   ```
3. It ends at a crossroad. E.g.:

   ```
    |
   =#=
    |
   ```
4. It ends at a roundabout. E.g.:

```
 |
=O
 |
```

It is **not** connected in (for example) these instances:

- ```
  |
   |
  ```
- ```
  ||
  ```
- ```
  | =
  ```

Moving one position up, down, left and right all count as traveling the same distance.

#### Output

- `Turn right`
- `Go straight on`
- `Take the {1st/2nd/3rd} exit` (at a roundabout)

You take roundabouts clockwise. Because of this, taking *any* exit amounts to turning right.

### Rules

- Each instruction must be on its own line.
- No other output is permitted.
- Your program may take no longer than a minute to run on an average home user’s computer.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, unless specified otherwise.

This is code golf. The shortest answer wins.

---

This is an early draft. Input is welcome, especially on the feasibility of requiring the shortest possible route, if this should be code golf, how input should be generated (randomly but the same for all programs? A few predefined maps?) and any improvements for the challenge. Any constructive feedback is welcome, even if it's just about spelling and grammar errors.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: [Very related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38467/your-car-only-turns-right)

Comment: @Sp3000 Not a duplicate though.

Comment: How are the roundabout exits numbered?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I've updated the text to say you take roundabouts clockwise. I hope it's sufficiently clear now.

Answer (score 0):

## Arranging Matrices

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (doesn't actually require any matrix math)

While doing homework on matrix multiplication, I realized that I could avoid rewriting all of the matrices by arranging them intelligently on the page.   If the problems were:

```
A * B = C
A * D = E
F * D = G
```

I could arrange the matrices like so:

```
 BD
ACE
 FG
```

This arrangement satisfies the requirement that each product (`C E G`) have the correct factors in the correct directions.  For example, the `A * D = E` so `E` is to the right of `A` and below `D`.

The challenge is, given a list of multiplication problems (in the same format as above), output an arrangement of them that involves the fewest letters (the above solution has 7, the minimum).

Comment: Needs a test case for an input which has conflicts. The easiest one would probably be `A * B = C` `B * A = D`.

Comment: You might want to first explain how for a single matrix multiplication you usually arrange the matrices to do the computation. I don't think everyone is familiar with the technique this challenge is based on.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello everyone! I've been lurking around for a couple of weeks now and I think this site is super interesting!*

*I've decided that I definitely want to contribute to this site as well and have composed a new challenge over the last few days, that I hope you'll find interesting too!
I've tried to do all the reading beforehand and hope that I've got everything right and that this kind of thing hasn't been done before.
Please let me know if you think something needs to be changed!*

*Anyways, here is my proposed challenge:*

---

## Programs With Taste [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

*[probably will add some "flavor text" here]*

#### The Task:

Write a program that takes an arbitrary group of pictures and ranks them after this program's "preference."

What that means is, you should come up with an algorithm that favors some attributes in pictures over others by comparing them in a specific way.

This is a popularity-contest, so what I want to see is interesting and creative methods of "pseudo-subjectively" ranking images.

As an example, one program could favor an overall more colorful image over a mostly gray one, or another could have a "favorite" color and ranks pictures which have it more, higher than others. You could even come up with an elaborate scoring system that combines a couple of criteria.

#### Details:

As input your program should accept any amount of images, which can be of any size.
It doesn't matter if your program requires them to be in a specific file format.

The output should be a ranked list from "favorite" image to "least favorite", with items that unmistakably represent each of the pictures (e.g. a list of file names or a list of the images itself).
If you want, you can also include the actual numbers (or score) that are compared in the output.

The program should definitely be deterministic, so that the same group of pictures will always result in the same order.

If you're entering, please also provide a short description of what your algorithm prefers in a picture and how it's calculated.

As a bonus task I think it would also be really interesting to see what "the perfect picture" for your algorithm would be, meaning that this image would theoretically always be ranked the highest by your program.

#### Example images:

Here are some groups of images you can use as examples:

*[I'll create and/or find some images to put here]*

You can download them all in a .zip [here](http://example.com).

**Good luck!**

Comment: Whats stopping me from writing my program so that it prefers pictures with a filename closer to 0 in the ascii table (sorting)?

Comment: @muddyfish Nothing, really. I wouldn't expect it to do well in a popularity contest, though. It's not a golf, so the length of the program isn't really a concern.

Comment: This is definitely "Too Broad".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you please elaborate? I don't really know much what you classify as broad on this site, but personally, I don't think it is, or at least not "definitely." I gave a specific and clear goal - to sort a set of images - while leaving enough freedom in the actual implementation to allow some creative submissions for an interesting popularity-contest. What do you think needs to be narrowed down?

Comment: In essence your challenge is "*Write any function you want from int[] to double*". That isn't specific. I'm not sure that it can be narrowed down sufficiently without becoming a completely different question (e.g. a classifier which distinguishes representational vs abstract art with a reasonable degree of accuracy - and classification questions have their own problems).

Answer (score 0):

## Oh dear, bad CSS! *or* How to Properly Format CSS™

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [css](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css)

*Please give me any improvements/suggestions you may think of.*

The goal is to write a short function to Properly Format CSS™; you must Properly Convert Spaces To Tabs™ and format the CSS nicely.

### Bad CSS™

```css
div> *
{
  padding: 10px;
     margin: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 2px 100%; border-radius:10px 2px 100%;
       border: 2px solid yellow;margin: 1rem;
-moz-border-radius:10px 2px 100%}
```

### Proper CSS™

```css
div > * {
--->border: 2px solid yellow;
--->-webkit-border-radius: 10px 2px 100%;
--->   -moz-border-radius: 10px 2px 100%;
--->        border-radius: 10px 2px 100%;
--->margin: 1em;
--->margin: 1rem;
--->padding: 10px;
}
```

*A tab is represented by `--->`, as you can't embed tabs properly on StackExchange.*

All the properties are sorted alphabetically, and nicely formatted (please also note that the order of the properties **can** be important, such as in the case of `margin: 1em; ... margin: 1rem;`. The selector is also nicely formatted.

### Format

- Format the selector with spaces around every token
- A space; a left curly brace (`{`); a newline
- One tab; optional spaces (see below); the property name; a colon; a space; the tokens, separated by single spaces <sup>*how do I define token?*</sup> (replace `0{unit}` with `0`); a semi-colon; a new line
- A newline; a right curly brace (`}`)

### Property sorting

Sort the properties alphabetically, ignoring prefixes. Then list each prefix for the property specified in the original CSS, starting with the longest, down to the shortest (i.e., none), adding spaces before the property name to pad the shorter prefixes to the longest prefix.

The same property may appear more than once; keep each variant in the original order, as in the example.

### Rules

1. You may not use any built-in CSS parsers and/or formatters.
2. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

### Bonuses

1. **-100** bonus if the function can also format psuedo-classes and elements properly (e.g. `p >a::before` to `p > a::before` and `p>a:visited` to `p > a:visited`).
2. **-50** bonus if you change `:after` and `:before` to the new, two-colon syntax (`::after` and `::before`).

The task is to provide a function to format (correct) some CSS (provided as a parameter) as specified above, not a fully-featured CSS parser – but you get a **-1000** bonus if the code is a fully-featured, forwards-compatible CSS3 parser! :)

**Input:** function parameter or STDIN.
**Output:** function return value or STDOUT.
No output to STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

### With Rhyme *and* Reason

A budding poet (you) knows not his rhymes

Lines of code he can write deftly and quick

And those of prose he can write mostly fine

But the poems he creates make him sick

Through study of verse throughout all forms known

Our dear programmer shall learn the right way

But alas, all of his lyrical tomes

Would have him reading until he was gray

At once a brilliant epiphany struck

Thought he, "A program is just what I need!

It will look for me and rake through the muck

Songs and poems of all kinds it shall read

And give to me solely their rhyming scheme

With which I can write that of which I dream"

---

### Your Task

Given an input, you are to output its rhyme scheme.

### Rules

1. You are to only compare the last words in each line when looking for rhymes. These will be referred to as "rhyme words."
2. For each stanza (lines separated by single line breaks -- think something like a paragraph), you are to assign the first rhyme word the letter "A." If the next one rhymes with any other preceding rhyme word, it shall be assigned the letter of said word (in this case, "A"), and if not, the next letter in the alphabet (in this case, "B"). Once you reach two or more line breaks in a row, you treat whatever follows as separate stanza.
3. You can code it in so that when you get past the letter "Z," your program wraps around and assigns rhyme words again to "A," but you should not expect that there will be that many rhymes in the stanzas provided. If your program errors instead, that is admissible.
4. Sight rhymes do **not** count (you must find some sort of way to compare the words phonetically)
5. Standard loopholes apply

### Input

The input will be in the form of a file, unless your language cannot read files, in which case it will be through STDIN. It will consist of at least one stanza of written text.

### Output

Your output will be either written to a file or the console (whichever is easier to read). Your output will consist of letters corresponding to the rhyme scheme as discussed in rule 2; you choose how they are formatted, but please format them in a readable fashion (especially for large inputs).

### Scoring

Your score will be the amount of rhymes correctly identified over the total as a percentage. For example, if your program returns `ABCA DDEE` when the actual was `ABBA CCDD`, your score would be `3/4`, or `75%`, because it got `AA`, `CC`, and `DD`, but not `BB`.

I do not expect scores near `100%`, due to the difficulty of this challenge, so if your score is low, don't worry about it.

[Here](http://hastebin.com/gopejezosi.py) is a link to my implementation of a scorer in Python.

---

### Test Cases

**Input: (Sonnets from the Portuguese #43)**

```
How do I love thee? Let me count the ways.
I love thee to the depth and breadth and height
My soul can reach, when feeling out of sight
For the ends of Being and ideal Grace.
I love thee to the level of everyday's
Most quiet need, by sun and candle-light.
I love thee freely, as men strive for Right;
I love thee purely, as they turn from Praise.
I love thee with a passion put to use
In my old griefs, and with my childhood's faith.
I love thee with a love I seemed to lose
With my lost saints, --- I love thee with the breath,
Smiles, tears, of all my life! --- and, if God choose,
I shall but love thee better after death.
```

**Output:**

```
ABBA ABBA CDC DCD
```

---

**Input:**

```
A budding poet (you) knows not his rhymes
Lines of code he can write deftly and quick
And those of prose he can write mostly fine
But the poems he creates make him sick
Through study of verse throughout all forms known
Our dear programmer shall learn the right way
But alas, all of his lyrical tomes
Would have him reading until he was gray

At once a brilliant epiphany struck
Thought he, "A program is just what I need!
It will look for me and rake through the muck
Songs and poems of all kinds it shall read
And give to me solely their rhyming scheme
With which I can write that of which I dream"
```

**Output:**

```
ABAB CDCD 
ABAB CC
```

---

**Input:**

```
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
cow
```

**Output:**

```
Error.
```

or

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
```

### What I'm looking for help with

1. <s>How can I figure out a way of easily scoring answers (this seems to be a programming puzzle in and of itself)? Maybe check to see if the characters used match</s> I've made a [scorer](http://hastebin.com/gopejezosi.py) in Python, but I'm not 100% sure yet that it is completely accurate.
2. Is this challenge too difficult; should I restrict it to only a certain few test cases?
3. Regarding test cases, I plan on making a large one for purposes of scoring - how many lines of rhymes would be good?
4. Would this maybe do better as a partially `code golf` challenge (factor in length with scoring) with the goal being to be able to give the scheme as accurately as possible for only a few test cases (although I believe that would make this come close to being a duplicate)?
5. Anything else at all that you notice

Comment: IMO "*you must find some sort of way to compare the words phonetically*" is too broad. You should provide a clear specification of how words should be compared. I suggest requiring the use of CMUDICT (and allowing it to be preprocessed to remove comments and then read from a file named `d`), and specifying that words rhyme iff their phonetics as given in CMUDICT agree perfectly from the most stressed vowel to the end. And have test cases which cover words with more than one pronunciation in CMUDICT.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think you're right, I'll look into CMUDICT, but judging from your comment it ought to be fine. If I allow it, I think I will then factor in length in the score. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

## Format the code

Given some source code in a C-like language, format (prettify) it using the following rules:

- remove all leading/trailing whitespace on each line
- collapse consecutive empty lines into one empty line
- if the first line is empty, remove it; same with the last line
- split lines after each occurrence of a semicolon (`;`) or left curly bracket (`{`); if it's the last character on the line, leave it as it is
- split lines at each right curly bracket (`}`), so that the bracket is on a line by itself
- remove all leading/trailing whitespace (if any) that appeared after splitting
- if a left curly bracket is alone on a line, move it to the end of the previous non-empty line, preceded by one space; any preceding empty line should be removed
- each line gets an indentation level: the initial level is 0, and is incremented after each left curly bracket and decremented before each right curly bracket; prefix each non-empty line with a number of tab characters given by its indentation level

The input consists of ASCII characters with codes 9, 10 and 32-126. The first non-whitespace character in the input is not a curly bracket. All curly brackets are balanced correctly. You don't need to do any special handling for strings, characters or comments. The output should end in exactly 1 newline character.

**TODO:** add examples, restrictions and more details
Oh, and it's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: You might want to add a special case for `for` statements, because splitting `for (init; test; inc)` over three lines with the same indentation is rather idiosyncratic and hard to read. (I would also prefer special cases for semicolons and brackets in character and string literals).

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh, I hadn't thought about `for` statements, that's a good point. At the same time, I don't want to make the challenge too complicated/difficult. I'm considering removing the semicolon rule, but I'm not completely opposed to your suggestions (I'm just not convinced it's better that way)

Answer (score 0):

### My first challenge in a long time. Feedback would be appreciated!

## Last Minute Shipments

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

Here's the situation: You're an engineer for Acme Rail Shipping Inc. There's a string of shipments to make for tomorrow but it turns out at the last moment that they're actually expected to arrive today! There isn't enough time to stop at every destination. It doesn't matter if you skip a few stops as long as you get to others as fast as possible. Your task is to figure out which ones to skip.

#### Challenge

Given a list of stops and a minimum number of stops to make, write a program or function that outputs the list of stops to make that results in the *lowest total time taken*. **Here's the catch:** Your train is very long and very heavy, so it takes a long time to accelerate. Sometimes it may be more efficient to skip a stop rather than to slow down to make it.

- Your train starts with the front at the origin and is at rest.

  - Each stop is a point along your 1D route defined by a positive distance from the origin.
  - To make a stop, you must slow down to rest with the front of the train on the point. The shipment is delivered immediately so right as you reach rest, you start accelerating again.
  - The train accelerates uniformly at 0.3 m/s^2 and brakes uniformly at 1.2 m/s^2 (*I'm not sure how realistic these values are. Subject to change. Feedback would be helpful.*)
  - Assume that there is no upper speed limit to the train. Therefore, you should be accelerating at every point between stops.
  - *Added*: **You cannot go backwards.**
  - *Added*: Total time will be measured from when you start to when you pass or arrive at the last stop, *regardless of whether you decide to make it or not*. You can't just leave your train in the middle of the route! This means that, for example, if you skip the last stop, then the total time will include the time taken for the train to accelerate from the second to last stop and reach the last stop at some velocity. If you don't skip the last stop, the measured time will end when you come to rest at the last stop.

#### Input

Input will be a number for the minimum number of stops to make, followed by a list of distances from the origin for each stop. The first item in the list will be the distance for stop #1, the next will be distance for stop #2, then distance for stop #3, etc. Distances in the list are strictly increasing and are defined in meters.

You can take input in any reasonable format, such as a delimited list on stdin with the first item as the minimum number of stops, as program arguments with the first item as the minimum number, or as parameters to a function.

#### Output

Output will be a list of stops to make. This list will contain the numbers of each stop, as defined in the previous section. For example, if it is determined that stops 2, 3, and 5 out of five stops need to be made, the output would be `2, 3, 5`.

Output can be any reasonable format, such as a delimited list on stdout, or an array return value from a function. Trailing whitespace or newlines are acceptable. The list doesn't necessarily have to be sorted.

#### Example I/O

```
Coming soon
```

---

Standard rules apply. Shortest code wins, however clever solutions will get my upvotes. Good luck!

Comment: This feels like a minor variant on the several existing single-source shortest path questions. It's borderline enough that I wouldn't use my unilateral close-as-dupe powers, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it closed as a dupe.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I did search before I posted this but I didn't find anything, maybe I didn't use the right terms. Are there any examples specifically that you are referring to?

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=shortest+path+is%3Aquestion Not *all* of them are shortest path in a graph, but I think most of them are.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I intended distance to always be the same, and the optimization to be for shortest time (I've updated the answer to clarify distance). The point here isn't that you must visit *all* nodes as fast as possible, it's that you must visit `n` of the nodes and decide which ones to pass.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. So the graph has vertices which are pairs `(stop, num visited)`, for each `k > j >= i` there is an edge `(stop_j, i) --> (stop_k, i+1)` with weight corresponding to the time to get from stop `j` to stop `k`, and you start at `(0, 0)` and want the shortest path to `(any, n)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Find Your Stack Exchange Spirit Pokemon [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

It's a popular game on the internet to take some numbers related to someone (usually their birthday/age), multiply them, and divide until you get a number between 1 and 720. That number is the Pokedex number of your "spirit Pokemon".

We're going to play the same game, but since this is Stack Exchange, we'll be using our user IDs. And since this is PPCG, we'll be writing a program to tell us what our Stack Exchange-based spirit Pokemon is.

To find it, take any user, then multiply their user ID by the number of letters in their name. Take that number mod 720, then add 1 (so 0 will become 1 and 719 will become 720). That's the Pokedex number of their spirit Pokemon.

**Input**

A valid user ID greater than 0, and a valid name, in this format:
`<ID> <name>`

The site does not matter, and it won't be given.

You may accept input from either the command-line or STDIN (or your language's closest equivalent.)

**Output**

The name of the user's spirit Pokemon (as determined above.)

**Additional Files**

Since there's no way you can cram 720 names into one program, you'll be given a file with the names of all the Pokemon (in order). Here it is:

```
Bulbasaur
Ivysaur
Venusaur
Charmander
Charmeleon
Charizard
Squirtle
Wartortle
Blastoise
Caterpie
Metapod
Butterfree
Weedle
Kakuna
Beedrill
Pidgey
Pidgeotto
Pidgeot
Rattata
Raticate
Spearow
Fearow
Ekans
Arbok
Pikachu
Raichu
Sandshrew
Sandslash
Nidoran♀
Nidorina
Nidoqueen
Nidoran♂
Nidorino
Nidoking
Clefairy
Clefable
Vulpix
Ninetales
Jigglypuff
Wigglytuff
Zubat
Golbat
Oddish
Gloom
Vileplume
Paras
Parasect
Venonat
Venomoth
Diglett
Dugtrio
Meowth
Persian
Psyduck
Golduck
Mankey
Primeape
Growlithe
Arcanine
Poliwag
Poliwhirl
Poliwrath
Abra
Kadabra
Alakazam
Machop
Machoke
Machamp
Bellsprout
Weepinbell
Victreebel
Tentacool
Tentacruel
Geodude
Graveler
Golem
Ponyta
Rapidash
Slowpoke
Slowbro
Magnemite
Magneton
Farfetch'd
Doduo
Dodrio
Seel
Dewgong
Grimer
Muk
Shellder
Cloyster
Gastly
Haunter
Gengar
Onix
Drowzee
Hypno
Krabby
Kingler
Voltorb
Electrode
Exeggcute
Exeggutor
Cubone
Marowak
Hitmonlee
Hitmonchan
Lickitung
Koffing
Weezing
Rhyhorn
Rhydon
Chansey
Tangela
Kangaskhan
Horsea
Seadra
Goldeen
Seaking
Staryu
Starmie
Mr. Mime
Scyther
Jynx
Electabuzz
Magmar
Pinsir
Tauros
Magikarp
Gyarados
Lapras
Ditto
Eevee
Vaporeon
Jolteon
Flareon
Porygon
Omanyte
Omastar
Kabuto
Kabutops
Aerodactyl
Snorlax
Articuno
Zapdos
Moltres
Dratini
Dragonair
Dragonite
Mewtwo
Mew
Chikorita
Bayleef
Meganium
Cyndaquil
Quilava
Typhlosion
Totodile
Croconaw
Feraligatr
Sentret
Furret
Hoothoot
Noctowl
Ledyba
Ledian
Spinarak
Ariados
Crobat
Chinchou
Lanturn
Pichu
Cleffa
Igglybuff
Togepi
Togetic
Natu
Xatu
Mareep
Flaaffy
Ampharos
Bellossom
Marill
Azumarill
Sudowoodo
Politoed
Hoppip
Skiploom
Jumpluff
Aipom
Sunkern
Sunflora
Yanma
Wooper
Quagsire
Espeon
Umbreon
Murkrow
Slowking
Misdreavus
Unown
Wobbuffet
Girafarig
Pineco
Forretress
Dunsparce
Gligar
Steelix
Snubbull
Granbull
Qwilfish
Scizor
Shuckle
Heracross
Sneasel
Teddiursa
Ursaring
Slugma
Magcargo
Swinub
Piloswine
Corsola
Remoraid
Octillery
Delibird
Mantine
Skarmory
Houndour
Houndoom
Kingdra
Phanpy
Donphan
Porygon2
Stantler
Smeargle
Tyrogue
Hitmontop
Smoochum
Elekid
Magby
Miltank
Blissey
Raikou
Entei
Suicune
Larvitar
Pupitar
Tyranitar
Lugia
Ho-oh
Celebi
Treecko
Grovyle
Sceptile
Torchic
Combusken
Blaziken
Mudkip
Marshtomp
Swampert
Poochyena
Mightyena
Zigzagoon
Linoone
Wurmple
Silcoon
Beautifly
Cascoon
Dustox
Lotad
Lombre
Ludicolo
Seedot
Nuzleaf
Shiftry
Taillow
Swellow
Wingull
Pelipper
Ralts
Kirlia
Gardevoir
Surskit
Masquerain
Shroomish
Breloom
Slakoth
Vigoroth
Slaking
Nincada
Ninjask
Shedinja
Whismur
Loudred
Exploud
Makuhita
Hariyama
Azurill
Nosepass
Skitty
Delcatty
Sableye
Mawile
Aron
Lairon
Aggron
Meditite
Medicham
Electrike
Manectric
Plusle
Minun
Volbeat
Illumise
Roselia
Gulpin
Swalot
Carvanha
Sharpedo
Wailmer
Wailord
Numel
Camerupt
Torkoal
Spoink
Grumpig
Spinda
Trapinch
Vibrava
Flygon
Cacnea
Cacturne
Swablu
Altaria
Zangoose
Seviper
Lunatone
Solrock
Barboach
Whiscash
Corphish
Crawdaunt
Baltoy
Claydol
Lileep
Cradily
Anorith
Armaldo
Feebas
Milotic
Castform
Kecleon
Shuppet
Banette
Duskull
Dusclops
Tropius
Chimecho
Absol
Wynaut
Snorunt
Glalie
Spheal
Sealeo
Walrein
Clamperl
Huntail
Gorebyss
Relicanth
Luvdisc
Bagon
Shelgon
Salamence
Beldum
Metang
Metagross
Regirock
Regice
Registeel
Latias
Latios
Kyogre
Groudon
Rayquaza
Jirachi
Deoxys
Turtwig
Grotle
Torterra
Chimchar
Monferno
Infernape
Piplup
Prinplup
Empoleon
Starly
Staravia
Staraptor
Bidoof
Bibarel
Kricketot
Kricketune
Shinx
Luxio
Luxray
Budew
Roserade
Cranidos
Rampardos
Shieldon
Bastiodon
Burmy
Wormadam
Mothim
Combee
Vespiquen
Pachirisu
Buizel
Floatzel
Cherubi
Cherrim
Shellos
Gastrodon
Ambipom
Drifloon
Drifblim
Buneary
Lopunny
Mismagius
Honchkrow
Glameow
Purugly
Chingling
Stunky
Skuntank
Bronzor
Bronzong
Bonsly
Mime Jr.
Happiny
Chatot
Spiritomb
Gible
Gabite
Garchomp
Munchlax
Riolu
Lucario
Hippopotas
Hippowdon
Skorupi
Drapion
Croagunk
Toxicroak
Carnivine
Finneon
Lumineon
Mantyke
Snover
Abomasnow
Weavile
Magnezone
Lickilicky
Rhyperior
Tangrowth
Electivire
Magmortar
Togekiss
Yanmega
Leafeon
Glaceon
Gliscor
Mamoswine
Porygon-Z
Gallade
Probopass
Dusknoir
Froslass
Rotom
Uxie
Mesprit
Azelf
Dialga
Palkia
Heatran
Regigigas
Giratina
Cresselia
Phione
Manaphy
Darkrai
Shaymin
Arceus
Victini
Snivy
Servine
Serperior
Tepig
Pignite
Emboar
Oshawott
Dewott
Samurott
Patrat
Watchog
Lillipup
Herdier
Stoutland
Purrloin
Liepard
Pansage
Simisage
Pansear
Simisear
Panpour
Simipour
Munna
Musharna
Pidove
Tranquill
Unfezant
Blitzle
Zebstrika
Roggenrola
Boldore
Gigalith
Woobat
Swoobat
Drilbur
Excadrill
Audino
Timburr
Gurdurr
Conkeldurr
Tympole
Palpitoad
Seismitoad
Throh
Sawk
Sewaddle
Swadloon
Leavanny
Venipede
Whirlipede
Scolipede
Cottonee
Whimsicott
Petilil
Lilligant
Basculin
Sandile
Krokorok
Krookodile
Darumaka
Darmanitan
Maractus
Dwebble
Crustle
Scraggy
Scrafty
Sigilyph
Yamask
Cofagrigus
Tirtouga
Carracosta
Archen
Archeops
Trubbish
Garbodor
Zorua
Zoroark
Minccino
Cinccino
Gothita
Gothorita
Gothitelle
Solosis
Duosion
Reuniclus
Ducklett
Swanna
Vanillite
Vanillish
Vanilluxe
Deerling
Sawsbuck
Emolga
Karrablast
Escavalier
Foongus
Amoonguss
Frillish
Jellicent
Alomomola
Joltik
Galvantula
Ferroseed
Ferrothorn
Klink
Klang
Klinklang
Tynamo
Eelektrik
Eelektross
Elgyem
Beheeyem
Litwick
Lampent
Chandelure
Axew
Fraxure
Haxorus
Cubchoo
Beartic
Cryogonal
Shelmet
Accelgor
Stunfisk
Mienfoo
Mienshao
Druddigon
Golett
Golurk
Pawniard
Bisharp
Bouffalant
Rufflet
Braviary
Vullaby
Mandibuzz
Heatmor
Durant
Deino
Zweilous
Hydreigon
Larvesta
Volcarona
Cobalion
Terrakion
Virizion
Tornadus
Thundurus
Reshiram
Zekrom
Landorus
Kyurem
Keldeo
Meloetta
Genesect
Chespin
Quilladin
Chesnaught
Fennekin
Braixen
Delphox
Froakie
Frogadier
Greninja
Bunnelby
Diggersby
Fletchling
Fletchinder
Talonflame
Scatterbug
Spewpa
Vivillon
Litleo
Pyroar
Flabebe
Floette
Florges
Skiddo
Gogoat
Pancham
Pangoro
Furfrou
Espurr
Meowstic
Honedge
Doublade
Aegislash
Spritzee
Aromatisse
Swirlix
Slurpuff
Inkay
Malamar
Binacle
Barbaracle
Skrelp
Dragalge
Clauncher
Clawitzer
Helioptile
Heliolisk
Tyrunt
Tyrantrum
Amaura
Aurorus
Sylveon
Hawlucha
Dedenne
Carbink
Goomy
Sliggoo
Goodra
Klefki
Phantump
Trevenant
Pumpkaboo
Gourgeist
Bergmite
Avalugg
Noibat
Noivern
Xerneas
Yveltal
Zygarde
Diancie
Hoopa
```

**Rules**

- The file containing all the Pokemon must be saved as "pokemonlist".
- You may not open any files other than "pokemonlist".
- The program must output the name of the Pokemon, not just the number.
- Your program must work for any valid Stack Exhange user name and ID.

**Bonuses**

- -50 points if you return "MissingNo." if the input `-1 Community` is entered.

**Meta Questions**

- Are the rules clear?
- Is the formula enough of a challenge?
- I had a problem with the previous formula being too easy, so I've changed it. However, I'm not sure whether the problem was in the formula or the challenge itself. Will this challenge work, or is it too easy regardless of what formula I use?

Comment: I sincerely object to any formula where I end up a Palpitoad.

Comment: On-topic: This is really just "print line X%720+1 from this file", right?

Comment: @Geobits Yes. I'll probably have to rework the formula so it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

## It's a small world! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A challenge inspired by [small world networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network). It is said that in such a network, starting at any point, you are able to reach any other node of the network in a specific amount of hops.

Your task will be determining the smallest number of hops necessary to reach any other node (maximum short-path length, aka graph diameter) and the average number of hops for the same purpose.

#### Input

Your program will recieve on its stdin some amount of lines, with space-separated numbers on it.

Line number `N` will list the line numbers of the nodes node `N` is connected to. Every node is linked mutually, there are no unidirectional eges.

```
2 3
1 4
1
2
```

Each line can be assumed to be sorted.

#### Output

Your program must compute the smallest number of hops necessary to depart from one node and land on any *different* node, and the average number of hops to traverse any node. Print it to stdout in any format desired. The average path length must be a decimal with at least 2 digits of precision.

The average path length is defined (for the purposes of this challenge) as the sum of the smallest number of hops between any 2 points divided by the amount of edges in the network (direct connections) plus the biggest short-path. The sum-of-short-paths includes the edges themselves (e.g. paths to neighbouring nodes), but not reversed paths (A to B and B to A).

```
sum(short_paths)/(edges+long)
```

#### Example

The network represented in this image:

[image: visual representation of network]

Will be input to your program as:

```
2 4
1 3 5
2 4
1 3
2
```

And the program must output something in the form of:

```
3
2.0
```

The average was calculated in this manner:

```
p12 = 1; p13 = 2; p14 = 1; p15 = 2; p23 = 1; p24 = 2; p25 = 1; p34 = 1; p35 = 2; p45=3
e = 5
A = sum(p) / (e+p45)
(5+8+3)/(5+3)
```

#### Rules

Basic [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules, avoid standard loopholes

---

I can see an issue with the "average" part of the challenge, since it is ill-defined and I consider this challenge quite extensive without it already.

Comment: It took me awhile to understand your notation for the graphs.  Maybe something along the lines of “line no. `n` lists the nodes node `n` is connected to” would be clearer.

Comment: I'm also unsure if the calculation of the average should be part of the challenge, mainly because I defined it arbitrarily, and because the challenge should already be long enough without it.

Comment: The average path length is well defined provided that you specify that the graphs will be connected. The other parameter is more of a problem: you call it "*maximum path length*", but that sounds like the longest path, and what you seem to be describing is the graph diameter. We've had a [couple of longest path questions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2304/194) already; we haven't had graph diameter or average path length, although arguably they're trivial variations on all-sources shortest path. I'm not sure offhand whether that's been done, or just single-source.

Answer (score 0):

## Robots on ice

### Part 1 - The basic

You are helping a robot `R` on an iced island. `R` can go
up/down/left/right. But since the island is made of ice, it cannot
move only 1 square at a time, but instead moves in straight line. Your
task is to help `R` reach `G`.

#### Input

The input (file, stdin, input, whatever suits you) is an `n×m`
matrice with the following characters:

- `R` The robot
- `G` The goal
- `#` An obstacle that stops the robot
- Ice

The island is surrounded by a wall: the edges of the matrice always consist of `#`.

#### Output

A list of instructions consisting of U/D/L/R, corresponding to
up/down/left/right.

The list should be the shortest possible. The distance traveled by the
robot doesn't count.

The output should be the map with the instructions on it, with each
instruction at the right coordinates. Each of `RG#`  should be
displayed if not overriden by an instruction (that will always be the
case for `R`)

## Example

Input:

```
##########
# #      #
#        #
#  G #   #
#        #
#    R#  #
#        #
##########
```

Output:
Since D,R,U,L,D is one possible solution, the output should be:

```
##########
# #D    L#
#        #
#  G #   #
#        #
#    D#  #
#    R  U#
##########
```

Another solution, U,R,U,L,D, should be output as:

```
##########
# #D    L#
#        #
#  G #   #
#    R  U#
#    U#  #
#        #
##########
```

Input:

```
####################
###R             ###
#  ######          #
#      #####       #
##                G#
###              ###
####################
```

Output:

```
####################
###R            D###
#RD######          #
#U L   #####       #
##R               G#
###U            L###
####################
```

You can assume that the puzzle always has at least 1 solution

### Part 2 - New options

The pitch is the same, but new characters can be displayed:

#### Input

The input (file, stdin, input, whatever suits you) is an `n×m`
matrice with the following characters:

- `R` The robot
- `G` The goal
- `#` An obstacle that stops the robot
- Ice
- `W` Some water. Robot doesn’t like water
- `B` a Box. Robot can push the box 1 square at a time, in front of
  him (not on the side), if the next square is  . It cannot be
  pushed into the water, through the goal… Robot cannot push 2 boxes
  at once. When pushing, the robot stays in place.
- `1` a numbered teleportation door. Always in pair. When entering a
  teleportation door, Robot will continue sliding in the same
  direction through the other door. Can be used more than 1 time.

The island will this time be surrounded by water.

#### Output

A list of instructions consisting of U/D/L/R, corresponding to
up/down/left/right.

The list should be the shortest possible. The distance traveled by the
robot doesn't count.

This time the output won't be displayed on the map, but on stdout. The
format doesn't matter:

```
UDRL
```

or

```
U
D
R
L
```

are accepted

#### Example

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWW
W W      W
W        W
W  G 1   W
W        W
W    1R  W
W        W
WWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
L
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWW
W W      W
W    #   W
W  G     W
W        W
W    BR  W
W        W
WWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
LLUL
```

The first L moves the box (but not the Robot) 1 square:

```
WWWWWWWWWW
W W      W
W    #   W
W  G     W
W        W
W   B R  W
W        W
WWWWWWWWWW
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
W         # W
W G 2       W
W           W
W   B 1     W
W#2         W
W   # 1R   #W
W          #W
W    #     #W
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
L #entering teleportation 1
L #pushing the box to the left
L #going to the box
U #entering teleportation 2
```

The solution `RULU` is also valid

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
W #         W
W     #     W
W#   1      W
W           W
W           W
W    1 R    W
W           W
W    G      W
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
L #entering teleportation 1
U #going to the wall
R #going to the wall
D #entering teleportation 1
```

In this situations, Robot cannot moves to the left:

```
W  GBR   W

W  #BR   W

W  BBR   W

W  WBR   W

W    R   W
```

You can assume that the puzzle always has at least 1 solution

### Part 3 - With help

Same as part 2 but with others robots:

#### Input

The input (file, stdin, input, whatever suits you) is an `n×m`
matrice with the following characters:

- `R` The robot
- `G` The goal
- `#` An obstacle that stops the robot
- Ice
- `W` Some water. Robot doesn’t like water
- `B` a Box. Robot can push the box 1 square at a time, in front of
  him (not on the side), if the next square is  . It cannot be
  pushed into the water, through the goal… Robot cannot push 2 boxes
  at once. When pushing, the robot stays in place.
- `1` a numbered teleportation door. Always in pair. When entering a
  teleportation door, Robot will continue sliding in the same
  direction through the other door. Can be used more than 1 time.
- `abcde` up to 5 robots that can move the same as Robot. They cannot
  go through other robots, including R, and can pass through the Goal.
  They can be sacrified by going into the water. They can be used more
  than 1 time.

The island is surrounded by water.

#### Output

A list of instructions consisting of U/D/L/R, corresponding to
up/down/left/right, prefixed by the name of the robot moving.

The list should be the shortest possible. The distance traveled by the
robot doesn't count.

As usual, theformat doesn't matter:

```
a:UDR
R:LU
```

or

```
aU
aD
aR
RL
RU
```

are accepted

#### Example

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W        a     # W
W   G            W
W                W
W                W
W                W
W             R  W
W                W
W       #        W
W             #  W
W                W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
a:R
R:UL
```

The answer `DLUL` is valid but not the shortest

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W                W
W                W
W                W
W                W
W  G    a    R   W
W                W
W                W
W                W
W                W
W                W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
a:U
R:L
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W           #    W
W                W
W  #             W
W           G    W
W                W
W                W
W           b    W
W   R       a    W
W                W
W                W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
b:U
a:UL
R:UR
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W                W
W           #    W
W          B     W
W  #             W
W     G          W
W                W
W  #             W
W   e       R#   W
W                W
W           a    W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
e:R
R:U
a:UL
R:LLDLUR
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W                W
W         G #    W
W   b            W
W                W
W           a    W
W   c            W
W           #    W
W   R            W
W                W
W          #     W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
a:U
b:RD
a:D
C:RD
R:RU
```

Input:

```
WWWWWWWWWW
W    G   W
W aBbBR  W
WWWWWWWWWW
```

Output:

```
a:L
b:LL
R:LLU
```

In this situations, `R`obot and `b` cannot move to the left:

```
W  GaRb  W

W  #b#R  W

W aBbBR  W
```

You can assume that the puzzle always has at least 1 solution

### Sandbox Questions

Has it been done before?

What do you think? Is it understandable? Should I do 3 separated
challenges (and in the sandbox)? More, less? Which part needs more examples? What part is
unclear?

I would like to go with shortest-code win. Should I use kolmogorov instead?

Comment: Similar: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50042/scientist-seals-stranded-upon-an-iceberg

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/build-an-ice-puzzle-generator

Comment: Well… that's too similar :( Too bad!

Comment: The fourth example for part 2 should have output LLLU no?

Comment: @quintopia Yep, it's edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Prove Your Language's Turing Completeness [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The goal is to show whether your language is or isn't Turing complete with the shortest program possible. This is different than "interpret BF" questions, since that's only one way to show the completeness of a language.

This question will maintain one for each programming language (using a snippet), so the goal is to have either the shortest Turing machine, or the shortest proof that your language isn't Turing complete.

Good luck with Malboge.

This is probably a weak question so far, and so it needs your suggestions!

- Also, I'm not really sure how it'd work for non-Turing complete languages...

Comment: Also, are there any languages whose Turing completeness is undecidable?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the shortest Turing machine*"? Are you planning to write a spec for an input format which describes the TM (according to a specified commonly-used definition) and its starting tape?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Not really. I could use some help with the wording. I really just want the user to show the [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) of their language, which could involve implementing Rule 110, or interpreting BF, or several other things. Or are you saying a need a more specific definition of what it means to be Turing complete?

Comment: I did actually start writing a comment asking what assumptions we could make about other systems being Turing complete, and then I saw that you talked specifically about having "*the shortest Turing machine*" and I rewrote the comment. If you generalise it then it becomes even more difficult: a proof that my language can implement all mu-recursive functions is really going to be a set of snippets showing how to handle each case, not a program. I think the approach which would cause least arguments would be to ask for implementations of a specific universal TM, and forget the non-TC langs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Do you know of any good ones that haven't been done? Conway's Game of Life, Rule 110, Cyclic Tag System, Lambda Calculus, and BF have all been done. I was really hoping for a generic, "implement a TC" code-golf...

Comment: I see the confusion: you're using "*Turing machine*" to mean "*Turing-powerful system*", whereas I was interpreting it to mean machines made of a tape and a finite state machine. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397596000771 includes the UTM which was used to prove that Magic: the Gathering is TC (2 states, 18 symbols): it seems as good as any for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

## Elementary Cellular Automata, My Dear Watson [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A seemingly innocent dinner party composed of [elementary cellular automata](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html) has just been turned into a murder mystery. One of the cellular automaton guests has killed the host! All that remains as evidence for who committed the crime is the nth generation of the perpetrator. Luckily for them, Sherlock Holmes is on the case.

Show Watson how it's done by taking an integer `n`, and a string representation of the `n`th generation of the murderous automaton and printing or returning a list of the possible suspects (the numbers representing the rule of each amphichiral elementary cellular automata, see the bottom of the linked page.)

#### Rules:

- The input string will have length `2n+3` for the `n`th generation.
- The first character of the string represents the values on the infinite tape to the left, and the last character of the string represents the same for the right.
- Assume that the automata start with a single `1` in the center of a string of all `0`s.

#### Example

Generation 0 of every automaton:

```
010
```

#### Notes:

- I don't have a reference implementation yet, nor have I created any examples.

Comment: What is this string representation? Will it be padded with zeros?

Comment: Then again, you would need a way to show the background (Rule 255, for example, would need infinite bits.) Also, should we assume that it starts with a single one in a background of zeros?

Comment: So wait... You aren't given the full generation? Also, do the generations start at 1 or 0?

Comment: Looking at your Mathworld link, it seems that you would need 2 background bits.

Comment: If I were a Haskell programmer, I would feel rather hard-done-by that the spec seems to require using an IO monad even if I'm writing a function rather than a full program. Is the special-cased output really worth it?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I suppose you're right. Updated. Also, perhaps someone could help with a reference implementation, or least some examples? The effort it would take me to create a solution is probably more than someone else. I don't really know a lot about cellular automata.

Comment: [Test case generator](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=256%2C%0A%7B18%2618%25!%7D%2C%7B72%2672%25!%7D%2C%20e%23%20amphichiral%0A%7B%0A%20%3AR%3B%5B%0A%20%20%5B0X0%5D%0A%20%20%7B_1%3C4*2%2F%5C*3ew%7B2_%40b%23R%26!!%7D%25_%7D%0A%20%2010%20e%23%20max%20gens%0A%20%20*%3B%0A%20%5D%0A%7D%25z%0A%7B%0A%20%20__%26%5Ceef%7B%7B1%3D1%24%3D%7D%2C0f%3D%60%5C%60S%40N%7D%0A%7D%2F). Each line of output contains a generation and then the amphichiral rules which give it. Change the 10 which has a comment about generations if you want to run more.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello, Loophole Abuse!

### Assignment

Print the following string:

```
Hello, World!
```

### Gimmick

you know the meta post "[Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)"? Yeah, those don't apply here. In fact, you're actively encouraged to use as many as possible and combine them in weird ways. the more you use in a way that other users like, the more chance people will vote for you.

In addition, to prevent trivial answers getting all the glory, your program must also work in the event that the characters that make up the source code are reversed (this includes the separate characters of a string). This includes external sources, multi-character compiler and execution flags, file names and anything else that is essential for the execution of the software (like Metagolfscript IDs).

### Scoring

This is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

Comment: See [this comment thread](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37520/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor If we can figure out a way to make the subjective part, i.e. determining which loopholes are broken, more objective, would that fix the question?

Comment: Relevant chat discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24349167#24349167

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I think it's such a pointless idea that I don't want to spend much time thinking about hypothetical changes.

Comment: Characters reversed means reading the program from last to first character?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes. So that means that, for example, closing brackets will come before opening brackets,

Answer (score 0):

## PPCG New Question Generator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Specification

Write a program that does the following, given a string `s` and an integer `n` (as a file, STDIN, or command line arguments):

1. Determines the `n` most used characters in that quote. If there are two characters that are equally used, the character with the lower ASCII value takes priority.
2. Returns the text and the character in the following format:

   ```
   Return the following text:

   >{string}

   But there's an ORIGINAL TWIST! You cannot use the characters {characters} in your answer. As this is code-golf, the answer with the least characters wins. Have fun!
   ```

Specifics:

1. You need to display {string} in blockquotes using Markdown formatting, not HTML. So if the string spans multiple lines, you need to prepend each line with `>`.
2. You also need to display {characters} using proper grammar and in order from most used to least used. For example, with "a", "b", and "c":

   > You cannot use the characters "a", "b", or "c" in your answer.

#### Example

In this example, `n` is 4, and `s` is:

```
I have loved flowers that fade, 
Within whose magic tents 
Rich hues have marriage made 
With sweet unmemoried scents: 
A honeymoon delight,
A joy of love at sight, 
That ages in an hour
My song be like a flower!
```

The output is:

```
Return the following text:

>I have loved flowers that fade, 
>Within whose magic tents 
>Rich hues have marriage made 
>With sweet unmemoried scents: 
>A honeymoon delight,
>A joy of love at sight, 
>That ages in an hour
>My song be like a flower!

But there's an ORIGINAL TWIST! You cannot use the characters "e", "a", "h", or "o" in your answer. As this is code-golf, the answer with the least characters wins. Have fun!
```

Answer (score 0):

## Remove Pieces from Chess Position Notation

You should write a program or function which receives a string representing a chess position as input and outputs or returns the position with only the pawns and kings left.

The positions in the input and output are described by [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) notation:

> Each rank is described, starting with rank 8 and ending with rank 1; within each rank, the contents of each square are described from file "a" through file "h". Each piece is identified by a single letter taken from the standard English names (pawn = "P", knight = "N", bishop = "B", rook = "R", queen = "Q" and king = "K").[1] White pieces are designated using upper-case letters ("PNBRQK") while black pieces use lowercase ("pnbrqk"). Empty squares are noted using digits 1 through 8 (the number of empty squares), and "/" separates ranks. *(taken from Wikipedia)*

For example

```
rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/2N5/PPPP1PPP/R1BQKBNR
```

describes the board

```
---------------
♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
♟♟  ♟♟♟♟♟

    ♟
        ♙
    ♘
♙♙♙♙  ♙♙♙
♖  ♗♕♔♗♘♖
---------------
```

With everything except kings and pawns removed it becomes

```
---------------
       ♚
♟♟  ♟♟♟♟♟

     ♟
       ♙

♙♙♙♙ ♙♙♙
       ♔
---------------
```

and expressed with the FEN string

```
4k3/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/4K3
```

### Input

- A [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string consisting of the characters `12345678PNBRQKpnbrqk/`.
- The input describes a valid chess game position.

### Output

- A [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string describing the position with knights, bishops, rooks, queens removed.
- Output might not be a valid chess position in some extreme cases.

### Examples

```
TODO
```

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Pareto optimality challenge

Write a class that maintains a pareto optimal set. This class must have these three methods:

k(int n): Constructs the class. N is the array size that all of the other methods must use.

boolean k.p(int[] n): Adds n if there exists no entry m in k such that each single term of m is greater than each corresponding term in n. The method must also return true if n has been entered into k, or false otherwise. n can be assumed to be of the length specified by the constructor.

boolean k.s(int[] n): Returns true if n was previously entered by the above method and there exists no other term m in k such that each term of m is greater than each corresponding entry in n. Returns false otherwise.

This is code golf, so shortest entry wins. Yes, programming languages without classes may be used, but all the usual properties of classes must be satisfied by the three methods above.

Answer (score 0):

## ASCII Snake

> > **NOTES**
> >
> > It was pointed out to me that we already have had at least 2 snake challenges before. However, seeing as they are from a couple years ago, I think another snake challenge would be nice. Below (from the description section to the end) I describe a "classic" snake challenge.
> >
> > However, I want to differentiate this from the classic challenge. I am more than open to suggestions in the comments below. My idea is the following:
> >
> > Make an "infinite" snake game. That is, every 10 points, the level changes and the snake is reset according to the following pattern:
> >
> > --The *n*th level contains *n* obstacles in the form of the '#' character. These work the same as walls. They are randomly placed around the map, the difficulty is that they cannot create a situation where an ungettable 'x' exists. for example:

```
------------------------------
| #                          |  11
|                            |
|              oooooo        |
|              o    o        |
|              o    v        |
|              o             |
|                            |
|                            |
|    x                       |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

> > would be unacceptable because if an "x" were to spawn in the corner, it would be an automatic game over. Also, the barriers may not form a wall which closes off areas of the arena.
> >
> > I can flesh out this idea more if you think it is any good.
> >
> > ## Please Give Me Feedback On This Question
> >
> > When I have a working question, I will begin work on a basic solution in C++.

**Description**

The goal of this challenge is to create a real time (non-buffered input) ASCII version of the popular game [Snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29) .

The board is 10 newlines by 32 spaces. 
The boundary consists of the " | " and " - " characters.

The snake body is made of the "o" character.

The snake head is v,<,>,^ depending on direction of travel (intuitively)

The snake eats " x ".

For example a game board might look like:

```
------------------------------
|                            |  11
|                            |
|              oooooo        |
|              o    o        |
|              o    v        |
|              o             |
|                            |
|                            |
|    x                       |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

In the new game, the snake has three body segments and a head. It gains one body segment every time it eats an "x".

The score (the number of segments+head) should be displayed somewhere on the screen.

The starting position of the snake and the starting position of the "x" is left to the writer.

After an "x" is eaten, the snake gains a segment, and a new "x" must spawn. "x"s may not spawn in a set of predetermined coordinates. They must spawn "pseudo-randomly" in the loosest sense of the phrase. This means that they can spawn using a random number generator or their position may be simply a function of the snake's position or some such simple rule.

The snake moves according to nonbuffered user input according to one or both of the following layouts:

"W" - change direction up.

"A" - change direction left.

"D" - change direction right.

"S" - change direction down.

AND/OR

"UP" - change direction up.

"DOWN" - change direction left.

"LEFT" - change direction right.

"RIGHT" - change direction down.

Note that, as per the rules of snake, at a given instance of the game, only three options are available to the player:

-- Do nothing (and continue moving straight)

-- Turn 90 degrees

-- Turn -90 degrees

Therefore, at a given instance, two of the movement buttons should be unresponsive. E.g. in the above case, only right and left are responsive.

Snake movement follows the normal pattern. For those of you not familiar with it: Let segment zero, $$s_0$$ be the head and segment $$s_n$$ be the very end of the snake. In a given frame, the snake has 3 choices, go straight, go left, or go right (from the snake's reference frame). $$s_0$$ moves into one of these spaces based on user input. Then $$s_i$$ moves into the space taken by $$s_{i-1}$$ on the previous frame.

If an "x" is eaten, then on the next frame the new segment $$s_{n+1}$$ is placed where $$s_n$$ was on the previous frame.

The game ends when the snake head collides with the snake body or a with a wall.

**Rules**

1) Only languages which are available for free may be used. Libraries may be used (for i/o, etc), however the actual snake program must be written by you. (if library overuse is an issue, it will be determined by up/down votes)

2) The game must be playable (i.e. the framerate must be acceptable on most machines, as determined by readers)

3) The **winner is the program using the smallest number of bytes** that fits the above description.

4) If an online compiler is available, it is recommended that you link it with your code so that others may play your game.

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)

Comment: FYI, we've had a couple snake-based challenges already ([1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7241/14215) [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4480/14215)).

Comment: Thank you. I'll either delete this post or come up with a way to make it fundamentally different. Since those were three years ago hopefully I can come up with a refreshing twist

Answer (score 0):

## Machine Learning

**If you give a downvote please say why!** (otherwise how will I learn, thanks)

The task is to create a simple program that "learns"

**-->The challenge** is to create a program which:

**(1)** outputs 50 integers (1 at a time) and waits for input after each.

The input given will be 1 or 0 depending on whether the number is "good" or "bad"  based on a predetermined pattern (see the pattern section for more information)

**(2)** The program will then output something to the effect of

```
<< Learning done. Ready for testing.
```

At which point it will wait for integer input.

**(3)** My script will then input 50 integers (1 at a time) and the program will read the integers and output 1 or 0 depending on whether it thinks the integer fits the pattern.

**-->Types of Patterns**

Patterns will be of the following types, in an unknown order

**-** is divisible by *x* (*x* no larger than 20)

**-** is greater/less than *x* (*x* no larger than 100)

**-** is a perfect square

**-** has exactly *x* prime divisors (*x* no larger than 3)

**-** is coprime to *x* (shares no common divisors with *x* except 1) (*x* no larger than 100 and not  prime)

*numbers above subject to change if a case is made in the comments*

**-->Scoring**

Bots will be scored on correct answers to my script input. The score is equal to the total number of correct answers across all 5 tests. There is a max score of 250.

Since I do anticipate perfect scores, ties will be broken by golf score of the source.

Further ties will be broken by submission time.

**-->Example of A Test**

note: "in" is for my input. "out" is for machine output.

The rule is "even-good, odd-bad"

```
out<<  10
in>>   1
out<<  1901
in>>   0

... more lines like this ....

out<<  Learning Complete. Ready for Input.

in>>   12
out<<  1
in>>   87
out<<  0

... more lines like this ...
```

Say the machine got 47/50 correct on this test, then it currently has a score of 47. I would then proceed to test it with 4 different patterns. And sum its score on each test for its final score.

**-->Rules**

**(1)** **you may not use external tables**, i.e. have a library that contains table for all possible tests. However, your code may generate such tables.

**(2)** **the bot may not exceed an *average* time of 2 seconds per output**. This goes for both the learning and testing sections. I really don't want to have to spend over 15 minutes per test. The *average* is so that it can spend a bit of start-up time to generate tables if it needs to.

**(3)** **Use of external libraries is permitted**, although it should be clear that the bulk of the work is yours. (this will be determined by downvotes)

**(4)** **Languages must have a free interpreter available**. If they don't I won't be able to test them. This rules out MatLab, Mathematica, etc.

**(5)** other rules may be added as necessary.

Comment: As interesting as this challenge sounds, I think you'd need a lot more than 5 test cases and 20 inputs to be able to see any sort of meaningful result.

Comment: Really? Why do you say that? Regardless, that shouldn't be a problem, I could write a script to test the bots.

Comment: Given only `5 * 20 = 100` inputs, I'd expect there to be only a difference of a few incorrect responses between the top answers, which is small enough to be caused by chance. Also, is there any limit on the size of the programs?

Comment: Okay, I'll bump it up to 50 questions per test. I'll edit the scenario shortly. No, no size limit (should there be), although I think that I'll put in something to the effect of "bot must make decisions within 1 min at all steps"

Comment: Mathematica is [free](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/).

Answer (score 0):

**Mutating variable**

**Output**
n number of lines (where n is from 10 to 30, each run is random) where each line is either (all of the lines have to be possible)

1. Array of n random chars (or String with n random characters) made out of letters only
2. random int divisible by n (by int I mean a whole number of any kind)
3. random double whose first two decimal digits is n (by double I mean an number that has decimal digits) therefore for n=12 it will have format ###.12####
4. random boolean true or false (by that I mean 1 or 0)

No two consequent lines may be same type

Another requirement is that in your code may call print (or System.out.println or whatever you use to print to screen) only once.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

By random I mean use your language's built-in random number generator,

Comment: Why the strange "may only print once" requirement? Also, for random, it might be better to use a [somewhat standard definition](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/14215) instead of "anything you like". That's just begging for the ubiquitous xkcd/Dilbert joke of constantly using the same output.

Comment: @Geobits I edited the question to accommodate for the random suggestion you proposed. And for only one line to print. I just thought it would make task a bit harder is all, and I tried it on a few languages I know, and it did make things just a tad bit more tricky.

Comment: Just a few more comments/questions: 1) You seem to have removed the part about all lines having to be possible 2) Is there a minimum number of choices for the random string/int/double? Otherwise I could just random between n and 2n, say.

Comment: @Sp3000 I added requirement where all the lines have to be possible. Also what do you mean by minimum number of choices? I didn't quiteget the question you asked.

Comment: You don't specify a range for the randomness, so the easiest thing to do is probably random between two possible options for everything, e.g. between `n`/`2n` for the int, or `0.n`/`1.n` for the double, and `"aaaaaaaaa"`/`"bbbbbbbbb"` for the string

Comment: @Sp3000 I thought that wherever I use word random I amply that they must use their language's random method. So if I say n random chars, I mean that every char has to be generated using the random method. How would I clarify that?

Comment: Well the problem is that this has nothing to do with a language's random method. I could use `random.choice("ab")` or `random.choice("abcdefg")` - both use the language's random, but there's more outcomes in one than the other

Comment: @Sp3000 so let the person use any random they like I guess. See no problem with aaaaa then bbbb and etc. As long as other requirements are met. The fun I wanted to see is printing all of those values and see the smallest amount of code.

Comment: If you're fine with that then that's okay then I guess. Was just checking

Comment: @Sp3000 so the question is ripe enough to post on the main site?

Comment: I think if you add the explanation for "consequent lines" back in it'd be fine.  The writing could be a bit better, but at least it's not as ambiguous now. Also, if by 10-30 you mean that 10 and 30 are both possible, then it might be good to write that as "10 to 30 inclusive".

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks for all your advice. I highly appreciate it! But I am leaving code golf for a while. As of late I noticed that it has become too toxic for my liking. Thanks for your help however :)

Answer (score 0):

## Ceylon golfer (whitespace + comment removal)

As some people might have noted, I'm [answering here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2338%20is%3Aanswer) often using Ceylon. This is usually done first writing a "normal" program, then slimming it down using whichever tricks I find, and at the last step remove all superfluous white space (and possibly also comments)

I want to automatize the last step.

Ceylon is syntax-wise a C-like language, so this golfer might be useful also for other languages. The details might differ, though.

This is similar to [Remove Whitespace from a Java Program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60230/remove-whitespace-from-a-java-program), but not the same, as Ceylon strings are a bit more complicated.

**Details**

A [Ceylon program](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/spec/html_single/#lexical) is a Unicode character stream, which can be lexically analized into a series of tokens, possibly separated by whitespace. (Only ASCII white space is allowed: space, tab, form feed (FF), line feed (LF), carriage return (CR).)

That whitespace is sometimes necessary – when otherwise the two tokens would stick together and form one token, or when a comment would become longer than before (but comments are to removed, too). Other whitespace can be removed.

Lines are terminated by LF, CR or a sequence of CR LF.

We have two kinds of comments:

- Multiline comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.
- end-of-line comments start with `//` or `#!` and end with the line (i.e. at the next line terminator).

Everything which is not whitespace or a comment is part of a token.

Tokens are of these forms:

- Identifiers or keywords start with a  (uppercase or lowercase) letter and then can contain letters, `_` and digits. They can also start with `\I` or `\i` instead. (Examples are `true`, `Integer`, `a`, `helloWorld`, `example1234`, `\Iexample1234`.)
- Literals:

  - numeric literals (decimal integer, hex integer, binary integer, formal floating point, shortcut floating point) have the form `[0-9_]+[kMGTPmunpf]?|\$[01_]+|\#[0-9a-fA-F_]+|[0-9_]+\.[0-9_]+(e[+-]?[0-9]+|[kMGTPmunpf])?` (where the `_` is only allowed at certain places).

    (Maybe that can be simplified to `[#$0-9][0-9a-fA-FkMGFPmunpf._]*`, with the dot not being the last character. Not all such strings are valid numeric literals, but I guess you don't have to figure them all out. The details are in the specification linked above.)
  - Character literals have the form `'` + single character (except `"` or `\`) or escape sequence + `'`, where an escape sequence is either a `\{` + a name or code of a character + `}`, or a `\` followed by a single (non-`{`) character.

    Examples: `' '`, `'←'`, `'a'`, `'\''`, `` '`' ``, `'\{#0020}'`, `'\{#212B}'`, `'\n'`, `'\{ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR GOLD}'`, `'"'`, `'\"'`, `'\\'`, `'/'`.
  - String literals:

    - A simple string literal is `"` + a sequence of single characters (except `"`, `\` and `` ` `` ) and escape sequences (see above) + `"`
    - An interpolated string literal (or string template) looks like a simple string literal, but can also contain ``` `` ``` + some non-string-code + ``` `` ``` inside the string. (In this non-string-code the whitespace and comment removal can be applied.)
    - A verbatim string literal is `"""` + a sequence of any characters, except `"""`, + `"""`. (There is no escape sequences or interpolation here.)

    There is further complication with multi-line string literals, but I guess for this challenge we can assume that there are no multi-line string literals.

    Examples for String literals: `""`, `""""""` (both the empty string), `"Hello World!"`, `"Escapes: \{#212B}, \{ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR GOLD}"`, `"""non-interpreted Escapes: \{#212B}, \{ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR GOLD}"""`, `` "some more escapes: \n, \r, \f, \t, \b, \\, \`, \', \"" ``, `` "punctuation: ' ` \" and more text" ``, `` """punctuation: ' ` " and even single \.""" ``,
- A lot of symbols are punctuation and operators:

  ```
   , ; ... { } ( ) [ ] ` ? . ?. *. = => + - * / % ^ ** ++ -- .. : -> !
   && || ~ & | === == != < > <= >= <=> += -= /= *= %= |= &= ~= ||= &&=
  ```

  The grammar is such that whitespace adjacent to one of those punctuation tokens is never relevant, so it can be removed.

**Challenge**

Write a program which receives as input a valid Ceylon program, and outputs the same program, with all comments and non-essential white space removed.

Whitespace is essential when without it two tokens would be one token – this applies specifically to keywords/identifiers and numeric literals. In those cases replace any string of whitespace with a single space.

(I guess there are some cases like `10else` where an integer literal can be joined with a keyword, but for safety it is better to always have a space in there.)

Of course, whitespace inside a string is highly relevant, so it should not be touched.

If a removed comment was the only thing between two keywords/identifiers, make sure to put a space in there.

---

*Open questions*

- I guess I should add some example inputs and expected outputs.
- How to score this? Simply as Codegolf, assuming there will be correct answers? Or give some example programs and see which entry succeeds to make them smallest?
- I guess most Ceylon programs to be golfed will actually be ASCII only – do we allow ASCII-only solutions, while giving a bonus for proper Unicode handling (in comments, strings, identifiers)?
- Do we require full programs, or allow also functions which take+return strings (or character streams)?
- Did I simplify the grammar not enough, or too much?
- I can imagine some bonuses for finding the shortest representation of an integer of float literal .. not sure if that is worth the complication.
- Another possible bonus would be to find the shortest way of representing a string literal (replacing some Unicode escapes by the actual characters, choosing between `"` and `"""`, etc.).
- Do we want to handle multiline strings correctly? Maybe as a bonus?
- Another possible bonus would be to remove strings literals which are not passed or assigned to anything (these are often used for documentation comments) – but I'm not sure how to define that without specifying the whole grammar.

  (Those have leadings space in the following lines, up to the column where the literal started, which needs to be removed when lexing. If we change the alignment of the string literal, we need to adjust those spaces too. Here it can sometimes be useful actually not include a new-line before the string to minimize that indentation.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Steganographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) Image Encoding

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) [steganography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography)

Write two programs, an encoder and decoder. Score is the sum of the source in bytes.

### Encoder Specs

Input:

- a lossless 24-bit color image file

  - could be anything from BMP to PNG to PPM
- an arbitrary data file

  - undefined behavior if one attempts to encode a too-large file in a too-small image.
- an integer value, *n*, from 1 to 8, indicating the number of bits to use per subpixel.

Output:

An encoded image with the arbitrary data stored in the *n* least significant bits of the pixel data. The data must be stored in the pixels, i.e. not in some hidden metadata. How the data is serialized into the 3-D image space (height, width, color channel) is undefined.

### Decoder Specs

Input:

- an image produced by the encoder
- the arbitrary file's length in bytes
- the same integer value the decoder took indicating the number of bits per subpixel.

Output:

- the identical arbitrary data file as was provided to the encoder

### Requests for Comment:

- Fix *n* to 1?
- Encode the length/LSB's used in the image so you don't need to specify them again. (e.g. fixed format for a couple pixels to define it?) Requirement/Bonus?
- Maybe have the arbitrary data file be another image of the same dimensions, a la [the Wikipedia example (cat in a tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_messages)? That could be kinda boring though; some very simple array operations could do it all. Or that could be clever. In that case, there's necessarily data loss of the hidden image.
- If *n* was one and this only required an encoder, it would be the same as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25443/hiding-information-in-cats), but this requires a matching decoder. One way encoding challenges I find dull.
- I'd be fine with using image libraries to load/save the image

Answer (score 0):

## Time Series Analysis

Time series analysis comprises methods for analyzing time series data in order to extract meaningful statistics and other characteristics of the data (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)).

### The challenge

Write a program or function that take a time series vector `ts` and output a the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) of a [simple linear  regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) estimated by the [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

The coefficient of determination should be the squared correlation between the predicted values of the model and the real values of the input, in such way that any perfectly linear time series should have `1`  as it's coefficient.

#### Considerations

- `ts` is a vector of racional numbers of length [image].
- To make the model assume `ts` is time sucessive and use time as its regressor.
- You **can** assume that `ts` is already loaded.
- You **can't** use build-in modeling functions such as `lm()` or similars.
- The input should be in any reasonable format.

#### Examples

```
# input
1,2,3,4,5,6  
# output                      
0
```

[image]

```
#input 
0.244,0.569,1.575,1.965,2.604,3.493,4.084,4.436,5.209,6.110,6.979,7.245,8.229,9.161,10.309
# output    
0.971
```

[image]

Let the shortest code win!

Comment: This could use either a link to a page that clearly explains the terms and method used, or preferably a better explanation within the post.

Comment: Good idea, I will link it.

Comment: The fact that this is time series doesn't change anything since it's just OLS estimation, which is not specific to time series. OLS requires two dimensions, so `x` is essentially position in the series and `y` is the value of the series?

Comment: I thought about saying time series to add some context, but yeah, it is just that, not sure about the output though.

Comment: What does `lm()` do?

Comment: @flawr `lm()` is a function in R for fitting linear models.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Objective**

Given a string in Markdown, determine how much of the string is in bold and italic.

**Test Cases**

```
**Bold** --> 0
*Italic* --> 0
**_BI_** --> 2
__*abcde*__ --> 5
This is in **bold and _this_ is in italic** --> 4
\**_BI_** --> 0
\\**_BI_** --> 2
This is not in ___ bold-italic ___ --> 0
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55834/8478)

Answer (score 0):

## Gif - Jif, Jif - Gif

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sub>The point of this challenge is to (not) settle debate on the pronunciation of "gif"</sub>
http://38.media.tumblr.com/11bc6092d29c8c6840f9e10184ca03fd/tumblr_mlksz8SLjn1qz4h3co1_1280.gif

---

The pronunciation of *gif* is debated and while it's supposed to be (and should be) pronounced *jif*, it's still commonly disputed.

In this challenge you will be given a set of words that have a *g* or *j*, representing the sound that the word is pronounced with. You'll also get some text in which you have to fix the incorrect spellings of *gif*.

Because this is the internet and everyone always wrong. It's (not) common courtesy to correct them.

[image: Duty Calls]

An example of a wrong pronunciation would be:

```
There was a gif of a mouse eating a burrito
```

The wrong spelling of *gif*? Unacceptable! This must be corrected immediately:

```
There was a jif (as in jar) of a mouse eating a burrito
```

---

Are we done? Nope, you're *still* wrong.

[You're always wrong http://travelsummary.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Im-Right-Youre-Wrong-e1363993322818.jpg](http://travelsummary.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Im-Right-Youre-Wrong-e1363993322818.jpg)

This must work the other way:

```
In the jif the cat wore a hat of a cat
```

This obvious misspelling must be fixed, we shall correct this to:

```
In the gif (as in graphic) the cat wore a hat of a cat
```

---

#### Rules

- You may assume all words that contain the letter *g* have the hard g sound (as in gravy) and all words that contain the letter *j* have the j sound (as in jam)
- Words will never have both *g* and *j*
  (Will add more specific rules later)
- Words must be picked at random each item with the same chance of being picked
- Words may be supplied through an array or the closest alternative for your language.
- Case must be preserved E.g. `GiF` -> `JiF`.
- You may write a program or a function

---

#### Examples

Input and output separated by a single line:

```
graphic, jar, jam, gram
I saw a jif of how to pronounce gif that showed gif is pronounced jif

I saw a gif (as in graphic) of how to pronounce jif (as in jar) that showed jif (as in jam) is pronounced gif (as in gram)
```

```
gravy, jeff
G is for gif, h is for jif, i is for gif, j if for jif

G is for jif (as in jeff), h is for gif (as in gravy), i is for jif (as in jeff), j is for gif (as in gravy)
```

Comment: Is the assumption that, if there's more `gif/jif`s than input words, that you cycle through the `g` and `j` words independently (i.e. for `gravy, jar, jam, gram`, you cycle through `gravy, gram` for `jif` and `jar, jam` for `gif`)? And do we have do anything special for soft g words, e.g. `generate`?

Comment: @Sp3000 forgot to specify that. I've made it so all words containing "g" are the hard g sound

Comment: "*Words must be picked at random*" from what source?

Comment: Has this challenge been posted? If not, may I take control of it?

Comment: @NeilA. You may but I don't think it'll be well received because it's a simple find/replace

Comment: @Downgoat: I will make a new answer with the same core idea but a few changes. Feel free to delete this if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

## Implementations of linked lists

Given the source code of a function or method to delete the first node having value *x* if existed, from a non-cyclic singly linked list, in a specific programming language. Write a program or function (not necessarily in the same language) to decide what kind of implementation it is.

You don't have to check for all the cases. But the more intelligent your code is, the better.

The possible implementations need to be checked are:

#### Pointer of pointers

(Spec and examples to be added.)

#### Head node

(Spec and examples to be added.)

#### Moving the data

(Spec and examples to be added.)

(And maybe some others.)

---

Possible winning criteria:

- Just [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).
- Something like [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) where a submission is valid if no shorter programs can do all the things documented in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Would someone like to write a crontab puzzle?

I have just asked for a software that [displays all times at which a cronjob runs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25935/display-all-times-at-which-a-cron-job-runs). As I think more about it, this might be a nice golfing question.

Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with the crontab specification, especially when it comes to combining operators such as

```
*/15,34,49-52 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Is that suitable for code-golf at all? If someone or a group of people would define it as a puzzle, I'd be glad to see it.

Starting point:

The program

- takes a crontab line as input
- checks if it is valid or not
- if valid, from now on lists the next execution times
- limited to a user definable amount

E.g.

```
program -n 10 30 17 * * *
```

produces 10 lines of output (assuming today is 2015-10-22 18:00)

```
2015-10-23 17:30
2015-10-24 17:30
2015-10-25 17:30
2015-10-26 17:30
2015-10-27 17:30
2015-10-28 17:30
2015-10-29 17:30
2015-10-30 17:30
2015-10-31 17:30
2015-11-01 17:30
```

Answer (score 0):

## Word Game KotH [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

First of all, I don't know what this game is called (or if it even has a name), but it's a modification of a game I've played a few times on road trips, especially with my family. I'll be thinking of a better name.

Any suggestions at all are very welcome.

### How It's Played

There are 5<sup>1</sup> bots playing per game. At the beginning of the game, they are given a collection of letters (which is not necessarily a word), for example "a" or "jet." The bots take turns in a predetermined order. When it is a bot's turn it is passed the current word(s) and has four<sup>2</sup> options:

1. It can change a single letter to any other letter.
2. It can add a single letter to any position in the word.
3. It can swap any two letters in the word.
4. It can split the word at any point.

If you didn't infer already, these actions are allowed with the caveat that their result is a valid word or two valid words, if the bot chooses to split. The game ends when the combined lengths of all the words in play are 3 times the length of the longest word in the dictionary used (e.g. if "onomatopoeia" is the longest word, the max length would be 36 letters since it has 12) or when only one bot remains. The bots are scored on how many turns they last<sup>*</sup>, and the winner of the game is granted a bonus<sup>3</sup>.

*The turn they lose on is not counted, so if the bot were to lose on its first turn it would have lasted 0 turns.

A word is valid if it is both in the dictionary and hasn't been played before.

Bots should take a reasonable amount of time in making their plays (no more than a few seconds).

### Available Methods

`isValid(word)` returns a Boolean value (whether the word is valid or not).

`getDictionary()` returns the entire dictionary as a single string.

`getPreviousPlays()` returns the words previously played as an array (one word per element).

Once any of the following methods are called, the bot's turn is over:

`change(index,letter)` changes the letter at that index to the letter provided. This method *cannot* change a space to a letter (to prevent stalling).

`insert(index,letter)` inserts the provided letter at the provided index.

`swap(index1,index2)` swaps the letters at index1 and index2.

`split(index)` splits the word into two by inserting a space at the specified index. Both of these words have to be valid<sup>4</sup>

If any of the calls to these methods are invalid, the bot is disqualified for that game (treated as a loss).

## Author's notes

1. Basically a random number I determined; I don't know if it's too big or small.
2. Is four too few to make this challenge interesting?
3. This bonus is undetermined as of now, but I'd say 2 points tentatively. I'm also a bit unsure as to whether that is a good scoring method. Should it just be on victories or position in victory (i.e. first, second, third, etc. place)? I'm also worried that this might encourage users to submit bots that collaborate to last as many rounds as possible.
4. Would it be more interesting if this ignored validity? e.g. if you have `candies dog` as the two words, splitting `candies` into `can` and `dies` would be valid even if either of those words had been played before.

I haven't done a KotH submission before, so I'd love feedback as to how to improve this.

### Unimplemented Portions

#### Controller

This is the big unimplemented portion: I want to get feedback on the idea as a whole before diving into programming out a controller.

#### Scoring

I'm still unsure as to how the games should be scored.

Comment: I don't understand how the game starts. If I'm passed a bunch of random letters, surely the majority of the time I can't make a word and I lose immediately?

Answer (score 0):

## Create [CHIQRSX9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CHIQRSX9%2B) Analogue Program.

[meta-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-golf)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task is to create a program in same language, that when given a CHIQRSX9+ will print a that analogue.
That analogue program will do similiar thing that CHIQRSX9+ program do. There's exception though. There's may be more than 1 instruction. Then it's meant to be executed

1. `C` => Read until empty line and print all entered lines, including empty line.
2. `H` => Print "Hello, world!"
3. `I` => Read input until a newline then return that analogue
4. `Q` => Print the analogue program source code. (Not the entered one)
5. `R` => Read input until a newline then print that string after doing ROT-13
6. `S` => Read comma separated number until newline and sort that.
7. `X` => For this, X have undefined behavior.
8. `9` => Print 99 Bottles of beer with correct pluralization.
9. `+` => Increment Accumulator.

Printing instruction(`C`, `H`, `I`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, and `9`) begin in a new line. After everything is printed, accumulator count is written at new line. Final newline is optional.

### Example

If there's program X written in Haskell, then

```
X
CH
>main=interact$(++"\nHello, world!\n0").unlines.takeWhile(/="").lines
```

Which when compiled (Example as W) will do that

```
W
This is a line
This is another line

>This is a line
>This is another line
>
>Hello, world!
>0
```

Another example for Q

```
X
Q
>main=putStr(s++[';','s','=']++show s);s="main=putStr(s++[';','s','=']++show s)"
```

Yet another example

```
X
H+
>main=printStr"Hello, world!\n1"
```

> Here is for indication of output. DO NOT print it.

### Sandboxing Question

How about scoring. I want to reward short produced program. However, shorness of producing program is also counted. I guess just 10A+5B+C. Where A is length of original source code, B is length of "QQQQ" analogue program. C is length of "CHIQRS9+".

Comment: Well, please tell me what's wrong in my question?

Comment: 1. I think this is a source-source compiler, which might be a more recognisable title than "create analogue program". 2. The HQ9+ family has a very mixed reception here, so you should probably expect some downvotes. 3. Why does the scoring system include a weight for votes?

Comment: 1. If it source-source compiler, Q will compiled to `main=putstr"Q\n0"` instead.

Comment: 2. What's wrong about HQ9+ except that it can be used to cheat at golfing.

Comment: 3. Just a tiny boost since "QQQQ" "CHIQRS9+" and original source code is already very big. Wait I'm writing it wrong. It must be subtraction. Else it will be penalty

Comment: Is that vote annoying?

Comment: Congrats on posting the 1600th answer in the Sandbox!

Answer (score 0):

**Goal**

The goal is to stitch several ordered lists of numbers into a single list that contains each of those lists as a contiguous sublist, with the numbers in the same order without gaps. The resulting list should be as short as possible.

**Input**

*n* ordered lists of numbers between `-2^63` and `2^63-1`

**Ouput**

A minimum-length list so that each input list appears within that list with its elements in the same order without gaps

**Example**

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3] [3, -38, 23424, 292] [0, 1, 2] [-38]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, -38, 23424, 292]
```

The output contains each of the input lists:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, -38, 23424, 292]
   [1, 2, 3]
         [3, -38, 23424, 292]
[0, 1, 2]
            [-38]
```

Comment: Many languages have built-ins both for flattening a list of lists and for removing duplicates, giving them a straightforward solution. I think that makes this too easy overall. The removing duplicates part is like [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59625/20260), though it uses characters and requires preserving order.

Comment: But it is not only about removing duplicates, but also about finding the perfect combination of lists, so you have to figure out in which order you want to put the input lists together. Also it might be necessary to have duplicates in the output to be able to have all input lists in there.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't realize the lists had to appear as contiguous subsequences. Let me edit that to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I found [notes about this as an algorithmic problem](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18434S06/superstring-lele.pdf), and it's NP-hard, so solutions are going to be exponential time. It would do good to include some test cases that a greedy algorithm would get wrong.

Comment: Looks like we [already have this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11623/20260).

Comment: Good catch. It's indeed the same problem. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

## Hello, World! Fitted in cases.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)

Your task is to take a line of input and print `Hello,world!` multiple times fitted to length of input. The cases of that character is fitted to input in same position(except shifted from deletion). If the corresponding character is non-alphabeth, you must use default case(lowercase except for "h" that is uppercase). And for punctuations, if the corresponding character is not punctuation, it will deleted. And if the corresponding character is space, the the ouput is space but it doesn't skip the "Hello,world" writing.

### Example

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

About punctuation deletion and space insertion

```
I have a dog. I name it Underdog.
H ello w orld H ello wo Rldhellow
```

Explanation

```
Ihaveadog.InameitUnderdog.
Hello,worlD!hello,world!hellow
Helloworld!hello,World!hellow
HelloworldHello,wOrld!hellow
HelloworldHellowoRld!hellow
HelloworldHellowoRldhellow
```

Other examples

```
.....&^&%&*%&(&)^$#()&#()&@#)*%)#1-
Hello,world!Hello,world!Hello,world

UPPERCASES
HELLOWORLD

lowercases
helloworld

Abdeg,fGhiJ.
Hello,wOrlD!
```

### Example Program

Here is ungolfed version of example program in Python. If there is error, correct me.

```
p=readline()
h="Hello, world"
i=0
k=""
for a in xrange(len(p)):
    if p[a]==" ":
        k=k+" "
        continue
    if isUpper(p[a]):
        if isAlpha(h[i]):
            k=k+upper(h[i])
        i=i+1
        continue
    if isLower(p[a]):
        if isAlpha(h[i]):
            k=k+lower(h[i])
        i=i+1
        continue
    k=k+h[i]
    i=i+1
```

### Sandbox Question

This language is surely need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## How am I doing?

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

My boss is a flashy sort of fellow. He likes all things animated.

He's asked me to write a progress bar to show the completeness of our super-secret project.

Now with me being me, I'm getting you to write this for me and showing the best one to my boss.

### Task

- Output a progress bar to stdout.
- Whenever a newline is sent to stdin, increase the percentage on the percentage bar by 1%
- If not already enabled and if possible in your language, set the terminal mode to non-echoing (stdin doesn't automatically get shown, think like when your typing in your password for sudo)
- You may not assume the cursor is in a certain position, it must produce a progress bar relative to where you started the program (no absolute jumps)

To help you, you may use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes), [ANSI colour codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) and any UTF-32 unicode points.

The winner is the entry with the most upvotes.

#### Sandbox Notes:

- Is this too broad? - I'm sticking to ANSI only but I'm not saying anything else about what it looks like.

Comment: Anyone care to say why this is worth a downvote?

Comment: Popularity contests tend to attract them (even the good ones).

Comment: This doesn't seem very tightly defined. Generally, the broader a popularity contest is, the more I expect it to gather downvotes.

Comment: Also, a simple requirement means most of the popularity of an answer will come from optional extras rather than meeting the spec. See [the line between art and programming](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/the-line-between-art-and-programming) for other's thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I'll just let this question die here (I'm not sure if I should delete it or not, I'm going with not deleting it unless someone else says otherwise)

Comment: I usually delete my challenges once I know for certain I will not post them, but for ones I (or someone else) might be able to salvage in future I leave them around.

Comment: I don't think this one is ready for main, but remember that here (as on main) a lone downvote doesn't really mean anything. It could be anyone for any reason - rational or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## Kaprekar Transformation

[Kaprekar Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_%28number%29) is an transformation a number by following that instruction:

1. Take n-digit integer.
2. Sort it anscending and descending.
3. Subtract the largest number and smallest number.

Your program have to do this:

1. Take 1 number, x.
2. Output all possible cycle and fixnums for doing repeated x-digit Kaprekar Transformation on all possible input. Rotation is considered same. So it is invalid to print:

   [00],[09,81,63,27,45],[81,63,27,45,09]

The output is a list consisting of list representing the cycle. You may using any style of list and even intermix it with restriction that it should not be ambigous. For example, comma separated item with item using comma separated item with enclosing bracket is OK, but not comma separated item with item using comma separated item without enclosing bracket.

Example:

```
8
>[00000000],[43208766,85317642,75308643,84308652,86308632,86326632,64326654],[63317664],[64308654,83208762,86526432],[97508421]
```

Or

```
>[00000000],[[43208766,85317642,75308643,84308652,86308632,86326632,64326654],[63317664],[64308654,83208762,86526432],[97508421]]
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2762/8478 ... also, for future reference, requiring one specific list format is bound to put an arbitrary set of languages at a massive advantage (those which can just use their native string format), while all others may have to do some non-trivial string processing which distracts from the (interesting) core of the challenge.

Comment: @MartinBüttner No, it is the generalization. You have to handle arbitrary digit this time. And you have to detect cycle and find all cycle given a digit.  Btw, there is typo. 2 39 is different example.

Comment: Task one seems to be identical. The fact that the other challenge only has to work with 4-digit numbers doesn't seem substantial. I'm pretty sure almost any answer there can be adapted to a variable number of digits in a couple of bytes. As for Task 2, I did overlook that. You could simply reduce the challenge to *just* task 2 (I'm not even sure why you'd combine two independent tasks into a single challenge?). Even task 2 can be solved by simply looping the solution to task 1 over all possible X-digit numbers, but there might be other ways to golf this one.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Then, why it isn't duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/hitting-495-kaprekar ?

Comment: Because it has been overlooked, I suppose. Fixed.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Maybe add time limit make this different enough.

Comment: I don't know. Since you have to output the entire list anyway, there is not much you can optimise beyond actually applying the transform until you hit a cycle. If you limited the challenge to the second task, a time limit might make more sense, but then again the second task might be different enough not to be a duplicate in the first place.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Then remove task 1 and it won't be duplicate? And add speed limit.

Comment: I don't even think a time limit is necessary for part 2.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Is Task 1 still have to deleted. And please, don't discuss in the Chat, because I can't access that. Better use my email: christianirwanhw@gmail.com

Comment: As I said above, I don't see why you would want to squeeze both tasks into a single challenge in the first place. (How would you score answers? Sum of the two solutions?) And if you split them up, then the first answer is certainly a duplicate, but the second is fine (and if you didn't split them up, I don't see why you'd redo the same challenge as part of another challenge either).

Comment: The cycle identification is borderline duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26578/194

Answer (score 0):

## Stupid leaks

Considering how [immensely successful my](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59865/leave-my-python-alone) last [two challenges have been](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62609/print-the-lyrics-to-caius-theme-final-fantasy-xiii-2), I'll do a different style this time.

*Drip, drip, drip, drip...*

It's the year 3000. Due to clean air shortages, a system was created that turns
water into air. However, that caused a *water* shortage (don't you love progress?).
Therefore, a new (expensive!) system was created to convert the air back into
water.

All that to say that water prices have *skyrocketed*.

And yet, here you are, stuck with a leaky faucet. Plumbers are expensive, but if
you do it yourself, you have to order the parts online and wait for them to get
here. You need a way to determine what is cheaper: calling a plumber and getting it
fixed in a day, or buying the parts online but having water leak until they get
here.

### The input

You need to take seven positive numbers as input:

- The price of water per gallon `g`.
- The number of drops leaking per hour `d`.
- The number of gallons wasted per drop `z`. This will always be a floating-point
  number less than 1.
- The price of calling a plumber to fix it `p`.
- The price of ordering the parts online `o`.
- The number of hours it takes for the plumber to fix the leak `l`.
- The number of hours it takes for the parts to get here `s`.

Only `g`, `z`, `p`, and `o` can be floats; all the rest will be counting numbers (integers greater than 0).

### The task

The gallons of water wasted per hour from the leak is `d*z*g`. For the sake of
brevity, let's call that rate `R`. If `R*l+p` is less than `R*s+o`, then you should
print/return `DIY!`. If greater than, print/return `Call the plumber!`. If equal,
print/return `Whatever...`.

### Precision

Floating-point precision through calculations is very...weird. Basically, your program can use whatever your language's default is. If you're using a language where the default floating-point type has infinite precision. If your language's default floating-point type can lose precision throughout calculations (like in Python, where `.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1 != .8`), then that works, too.

Short version: floating-point semantics and precision are however your language is by default.

### Scoring

Code-golf. Shortest wins. Standard loopholes banned.

Comment: What is a "counting number"? Does it include 0? You also might want to specify at what precision the equality will be checked (presumably hundredths?), and how rounding should be handled for the "Whatever..." case.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Is this better?

Comment: My language doesn't support floating point at all, so can I always just output `Whatever...`? More seriously, I'm failing to see the point of this question. Do some trivial arithmetic and then output one of three strings which between them take up 90% of the code?

Comment: I think it is better, but I think you do have to spend a bit addressing Peter's comment about languages that don't support floats.

Answer (score 0):

## Print a sourcecode

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Given 2 inputs(First input is truthy/falsy, second input is program in same language as submission):

1. If the first input is truthy then transform the second input into same program but printing the source code(After modification) first.
2. If the first input is falsy then transform the second input into same program but after the program finished it prints the source code(After modification). If the program doesn't halt, you may or may not modify the program.

It's code-golf, so the shorter answer is the winner.

For example in CJam, I don't write the program to do this. (> means output)

```
0 q
>{"_~"q}_~
0 0 1{_@+}11*;
>{"_~"0 0 1{_@+}11*;}_~
1 q
> {q](\o"_~"}_~
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what this question is asking. Would it be okay if you posted examples?

Comment: @Sp3000 Please undo your downvote. The example is fixed.

Comment: I didn't downvote though...

Answer (score 0):

## Show How a Regex Is Matched

**What your program or function should do:**

1. Accept input of two strings; let's call them `r` and `s`.
2. Determine whether `r` is a valid regular expression (you can use any common definition of regex for this purpose, or any common definition of regexes but with lookahead and lookbehind removed; indicate which you're using). Otherwise, don't output.
3. If so, determine whether `s` matches `r` as a regex. Otherwise, don't output.
4. If so, output/print, in order, the part of `r` matched by each character of `s`, and also the part of `s` that matches it.

**Note:** You *may* use your language's regex-matching library for this.

**Example:**

> Using PCRE; my inputs and outputs are `r` first and then `s`.
>
> `^.el*(o.*)*d\b` and `Hello, world!`
>   → `^.ello......d\b` and `Hello, world`
>
> `.\1\W` and `800-555-1212`
>   → `..\W` and `00-`
>
> `\b` and `a`
>   → `\b` and *empty string*
>
> `\d` and `a`
>   → *no output* (it doesn't match)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)

---

<sub>First floated [in chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=25012200#25012200).

Not a dupe of [Compile Regexes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7024) (which asks you to match regexes whereas this allows you to use the resources of your language to do so).</sub>

Comment: 1. It sure *looks* like a dupe to me: what's your argument for it not being a trivial transformation of the previous question? 2. In your examples, you seem to try to draw a distinction between outputting the empty string and not outputting anything. How does that work? 3. What exactly is the output format? E.g. the first example and the second example don't seem to be consistent in their treatment of metacharacters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. It's not a dupe at all: the older question asks you to match regexes whereas this allows you to use the resources of your language to do so; also, the older question outputs a means of determining matching, without regard to *how* it's matched, whereas this requires an output of the latter. 2. This question is OBE because of the edit I'm doing to fix #3. 3. Yeah, I messed up an example: I'll fix that immediately.

Comment: 1. With respect to the second half, see "*simple transformation*". But the first half is relevant, and worth editing in to the "*Not a dupe*" sentence. 3. I still can't figure out the output format from the examples. Obviously you want to ensure that it's not as trivial as asking the regex engine for group 0, but I think you need to first write a clear spec for the output and then write the examples (or, better, write a reference implementation to generate the examples).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, yeah, I'll have to work on it some more. If anyone else has ideas, please chime in!

Answer (score 0):

## Python assembler

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Python is a hybrid interpreted language. It first gets compiled into byte-code and then gets interpreted.

What does this byte-code look like you may ask? The [dis module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) disassembles python code. [Source code for dis module here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/dis.py)

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

Gets disassembled into the following assembly.

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello, World!')
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE
              5 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

The output is divided in the following columns:

1. the line number, for the first instruction of each line
2. a labelled instruction, indicated with >>,
3. the address of the instruction,
4. the operation code name,
5. operation parameters, and
6. interpretation of the parameters in parentheses.

**The disassembly of a basic for loop**

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

gives

```
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 28)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                11 (to 27)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  2          19 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             22 PRINT_ITEM
             23 PRINT_NEWLINE
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   27 POP_BLOCK
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

### Your task:

Given some python code that has been disassembled, recreate the original code object as close as you can. You can take the disassembled code through any method you chose.

Your program will output all the arguments to recreate a [python code object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16123158/3398583)

That is to say your program will output the following

```
0,             
0,      
nlocals,              
stacksize,            
0,                
codestring,           
consts,               
names,                
varnames,             
"a string here",            
"another string here",
0,        
lnotab,               
(),             
()
```

You can work out the variables listed above but you have to output it all, even the constants.

- nlocals - The number of local variables
- stacksize - The maximum number of values held on the stack at once
- codestring - A binary containing all the opcodes and their arguments
- consts - A tuple of constants
- names - A tuple of global variables
- varnames - A tuple of local names (length of nlocals)
- lnotab - A tuple containing a map of bytecode positions to line numbers

You may use the following code to disassemble a .pyc file:

```
import sys, dis, marshal

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as code_f:
    code_f.read(8) # Magic number and modification time
    code = marshal.load(code_f)
    dis.dis(code)
```

**This is code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins**

### Sandbox notes

Wow that was a long one. Perhaps too long?

Is the spec completely tight?

Should I explain anything further?

Am I making it too hard for non-python entries to take part?

Should I only make it a requirement to reassemble code without any functions/classes? I'm pretty sure `dis` doesn't show all that.

Comment: For one thing, yes this looks very hard for non-Python entries to me. For another, I think there's too much going on at once (there's a lot to output), and you don't explain much about how to output each specific component (ideally the post should be self-contained enough to work out what to do without knowing too much about Python/dis)

Answer (score 0):

## Vigenère Cipher

Write a program that is capable of breaking a text encyripted using Vigenère cipher encyription.

#### Goals:

- Take *encripted text* from STDIN and write *plaintext* to STDOUT.

#### Limits

- *Keyword* will always be 3 letters in length.
- *Plaintext* will always be in between 5-10 letters in length (inclusive).
- All *Plaintext*s, *Keyword*s and *Encyripted Text*s will be in English.

#### Scoring:

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

I'm not sure if this is a valid and solvable question, so any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: [Dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59091/crack-a-vigen%C3%A8re-cipher)

Comment: I'm not sure this can actually be done without having a big dictionary for such a short piece of text.  (Also, what does "encrypted texts will be English" mean?)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It means they will only contain english characters, no special letters from other languages.

Comment: Then write "consist of the letters A-Z" instead (or similar if you allow spaces and punctuation – though that needs more specification).

Comment: For Vigenere, in general you can either try a "plaintext dictionary attack" (which means you'll have a list of valid plaintext words, like in the question linked by Mego – that would be a plain duplicate), or you try analysis of character frequencies or repetitions, which need a lot longer ciphertext in order to analyze anything useful.
(Or you just output all possible plaintexts, and let the task of recognizing the correct one to some human.)

Answer (score 0):

## List Style Converter

[code:golf]

### Task

Given a list, format it into list of the choice of the input. The list will be list of item defined below, but it can be multidimensional.

### List Styles

There is 2 list separators:

1. Space
2. Comma

   For one dimensional list, only one separator is accepted. Space and only space between item is considered as separator. It is impossible to have more than 2 dimension without enclosing list of second dimension or third dimension. when parsing list, comma takes lower precedence and it is parsed with least dimension as possible. Space is optional between `]` with `[`; `}` with `{`; and `)` with `(`

   There is 3 list enclosure:
3. [...]
4. (...)
5. {...}

   Closing bracket must be present.

### Item

There is 2 types of item, another list or those following regex `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` or everything enclosed with single quote or double quote. If enclosed with single quote, it can contains double quote and vice versa. There is no zero-length item

Here is valid non-list item

```
98Az
Helloworld
"Hello, world!"
"It's house."
```

Here is the list

```
Hello, World!
Space then it is list
()
```

Here is invalid item.

```
!$%#%^$*%%^&%^&$%#:;,./<>?
Helloworld!
```

### Input

The input consist of string of number then space then list as defined above. The number indicates the output format.

There are n digit of number where n is dimension of the input array. each number correspond with this one. (Table formatting needed). The dimension is counted from outer into inner. You may assume that there is no two `0` or `1` without being separated by `2` - `7`.

1. `0` = unenclosed comma list
2. `1` = unenclosed space list
3. `2` = parantheses enclosed comma list
4. `3` = parantheses enclosed space list
5. `4` = square bracket enclosed comma list
6. `5` = square bracket enclosed space list
7. `6` = curly bracket enclosed space list
8. `7` = curly bracket enclosed space list

### Output

A identical list but with formatting changed according to input (i.e. each item it list is identical). Space not between list is allowed

### Test cases

`>` denotes output `#` denotes comment

```
6 Hello, world
> {Hello world}
5 (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21)
> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
#Alternatively
> [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
#Or
> [ 1,1, 2,3, 5,8, 13,21 ]
#But it is invalid
> [1,1, 2,3, 5,8, 1 3,2 1]
#Also
> [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,]
10 Hello, I am doctor
#Parsing rules that space separator bound tighter
> Hello I,am,doctor
01 Hello, I am doctor
> Hello, I am doctor
0 "Not to be confused be space or comma in a quoted item"
> "Not to be confused be space or comma in a quoted item"
51 [1,2] [3,4]
> [1 2,3 4]
51 [1,2][3,4]
> [1 2,3 4]
```

### Sandbox Question.

The format needs helps. Needs pointing when there is ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand this. To take a couple of your examples, `Hello, World!` appears to have two separators (a comma and a space): is it a one-dimensional three-element list, or a two-dimensional list? Is `()` a one-dimensional list or a two-dimensional list? And in the input, which order are the dimensions listed in, and what constraints are there on which formats can be used at which levels? (E.g. `00` is clearly not going to work, but I'm not sure whether `010` is permitted).

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's why I post the challenge here, because this challenge is nontrivial to writing. It is one dimensional comma separated list. Only space between item is list separator. Comma (except inside quote) isn't valid part of item. The input order is from outer into inner. You can assume that 00 and 010 isn't never entered.

Comment: `()` is one-dimensional list since you have to `it is parsed with least dimension as possible`

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm even more confused than before about spaces and commas. You seem to be saying that in the example `6 Hello, world` a (comma plus space) makes a single separator in a one-dimensional list, whereas in `10 Hello, I am doctor` a (comma plus space) is two distinct separators in a two-dimensional list. Do you have a reference implementation which we might be able to use to reverse-engineer the spec while the question is still in the sandbox?

Comment: In "Hello, world", "Hello" and "World" can be 1-item space separated list, however, lowest dimension takes precedence. In "Hello, I am a doctor" It is list containing 2 item. One is 1-item list, other is 4-item list.

Answer (score 0):

## Wildcard Golf

## Introduction

I've read this problem long time ago somewhere but I still don't know what's the best solution, so I'm posting it here. I don't remember the original author or wording so here is all in my own words.

This is different from [regex golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17718/194) because only two wildcards, `*` (equivalent to the regex `.*`) and `?` (equivalent to the regex `.`), are allowed.

## Challenge

You are given two lists of strings. You need to generate the shortest wildcard that matches all strings in the first list (the wanted-list) and none in the second list (the unwanted-list). In the wildcard, you can use `*` to match 0 or more chars and use `?` to match any one char.

For simplicity we can assume that inputs only have lowercase English characters and each string won't be longer than 100 characters. But the list can be very long (like several thousand), so speed of your program is important.

The correct answer that has the lowest average-case theoretic time complexity wins. In a tie, an easier-to-read answer wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

- Wanted list: abacum, academ, alarm, adam
- Unwanted list: alien, african, atom

One possible output:
`a?a*`

I'd also like to hear about how to approach this problem, and how to prove the theoretic lower bound of time/space complexity.

---

I'm new to this so comments are welcome. I'm not sure if my winning criteria is clear and practical. Also I don't know what tags I should put there. This is not a code-golf question.

Comment: It's [already been done](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17718/194)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @peter-taylor. This challenge is different in terms of using wildcards, not regex. So you think it is not worthy to post?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using *wildcard* as a synonym of *regex*. I take the point that removing alternation does make quite a different problem. Although it has the downside that there are insoluble cases (e.g. I don't think your wildcards can separate a wanted list of `a` and `abba` from an unwanted list of `aba`), so you'd need to specify how those cases should be handled.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit and clarify these concerns.

Answer (score 0):

## Triangularity

[image: The diagram of the triangle the program needs to solve.]

This is a challenge where you have to work out the length of `a` given `w` and `h`.

To qualify as a correct solution:

1. The program uses STDIN to get the values of `w` and `h`.
2. The program uses STDOUT to output the value of `a` in the above diagram.

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Tags: code-golf, maths

Comment: What's the formula? Unless it's very complicated, I expect it will be totally straightforward to golf.

Comment: @xnor, `a = w/2 * sin(atan(h/w))`. The diagram throws in some irrelevancies and omits a relevant line, but it's not an interesting problem.

Comment: @Peter Should I post this or do you think it's too easy?

Comment: @Tobsta I think it's too straightforward. Languages with trig will use the formula Peter gave, and the rest will do something like `h*w/sqrt(h*h+w*w)/2`.

Comment: @xnor Ok, got it

Answer (score 0):

## Typographic Chemistry

Inspired by this: https://xkcd.com/1442/

### Task

You must make a program or function that take input a string from STDIN and output the possible allowed reactions (1 point per unique reaction, see also "Score" below)

### Rules

A chemical reaction is allowed if all the "legs" of the elements are used, i.e., there are no unpaired "legs". A "leg" is just the end of a curve in the typographic print of the chemical symbol (see the comic and it should be clear).
 So for example:

Carbon - C - 2 legs

Oxygen - O - 0 legs

Hydrogen - H - 4 legs

Nitrogen - N - 2 legs

Potassium - K - 4 legs

Phosphorus _ P 1 leg

An element can be rotated, reflected but not stretched in any way, so that the only possible bonds are (here I don't know how to rotate the chars, if somebody can help it would be welcome):

$$CH \;\mathrm{(with\;the\;C\;on\;top\;or\;bottom\;rotated\;by\;90\;degrees)}\\CK \;\mathrm{(with\;the\;C\;on\;top\;or\;bottom\;rotated\;by\;90\;degrees\;or\;to\;the\;right\;rotated\;by\;180)}\\
HK\;\mathrm{(on\;top\;of\;each\;other\;or\;on\;the\;side\;rotating\;one\;by\;180)}\\
NN\;\mathrm{(with\;one\;reflected\;has\;two\;legs\;on\;top\;and\;two\;diconnected\;legs\;on\;bottom)}\\
P\;\mathrm{(with\;anything)}\\
O\;\mathrm{doesn't\;bond}$$

These are the only possible elements passed from STDIN. Notice that the difference between H and K is that K can bond also laterally with a C.

#### Extra Rule

If no reaction is possible, the output should be equal to the input

### Score

1 point per reaction.
Bonus: X3 the score if you can print the reaction diagramatically, i.e. print the shape of the molecule (like in the comic)

### Example

$$Input \rightarrow Output\\
C\,C \rightarrow (C_2)\\
N \, N \rightarrow N \, N\\
C\,N \, N\,P\,P \rightarrow (C N_2 P_2)\\
C\,C\,K \, H\,H\rightarrow (KC_2H_2)\\
C\,H\,O\rightarrow C\,H\,O
$$

Comment: Your rules seem to be imposing extra grid-alignment constraints on the letters (e.g. you don't seem to permit the hydrogen crystal from the xkcd). Does that mean that although P can bond with anything except O, the positions in which it can do so are restricted?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to impose necessarily the extra grid alignment, thanks for noticing it. Yes, P can bond with anything, I added it so that it is easier to have "allowed" reactions.

Comment: So does that mean e.g. that `CP_2` is possible?

Comment: yes it is, although I have no idea how you could print it. Do you have any good way to state the rules simply and effectively?

Comment: This is so far from the truth of chemistry that you really need some decent drawings to show what's acceptable. The number of bonds an atom can make is in reality determined by its column  in the periodic table:  K=1 (except the bond is usually ionic not covalent), H=1, C=4, N=3, P=3 (sometimes 5), O=2.

Comment: Hi, I have prepared an image, but I can't upload it because I don't have enough reputation. Can you help me?

Comment: The easiest solution I can see is to remove entirely the list of possible bonds and the bonus and to effectively convert it into a question of whether there exists a graph with the desired [degree sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DegreeSequence.html). IMO that's still an interesting question, and one which hasn't been asked here before.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ Expression Matching

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

So, I like C++. And I like regex matching puzzles (heck, "regex golf" is what first got me lurking on this site). Might as well try to sort of combine the two!

## Rules

Write a full program that takes as input two lists of zero to five integers in the range [1, 127], and outputs a string representation of a C expression that evaluates to *nonzero / true* for all integers in the first list, and *zero / false* for all integers in the second list. Input can be taken in any convenient form.

As a special case, if the second list is empty, then the expression returned must evaluate to true for *only* the integers in the first list, and false for *all other* integers in the range [1, 127]. Likewise, if the first list is empty, it should evaluate to false for the integers in the second list, and true for all others in that range.

The program will not receive two empty lists as input. If both lists are non-empty, there are no requirements on the result of the output when evaluated with an integer not in the input. (any return value is fine, as is undefined behavior, division by 0, etc).

The following tokens may be used in the expression:

- Integer literals in decimal, hex, or [octal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40713/sabotage-the-coding-standards/40740#40740), with optional `U` and/or `LL` suffix to denote unsigned / long long ints.
- A single `int` variable, which will contain each of the integers from the input in turn. The variable can have any legal variable name.
- Any of the unary operators `+ - ! ~`
- Any of the binary operators `+ - * / % << >> < > <= >= == != & | ^ && || ,`
- The ternary operator `?:`
- Parentheses.
- Operators that mutate their arguments (`++ --`, `= += -=` etc.) are not allowed.
- Character literals (`'a'`, `'_'`, `'\0'`, etc.) are not allowed.

Some examples of possible outputs:

```
true            false           sample expression
[1, 3, 5, 7],   [2, 4, 6, 8]    c%2
[5, 6, 10],     [2, 8, 16]      t&~-t
[7, 14, 21],    []              22>x&!(x%7)
```

(*TODO*: Specify undefined / implementation-defined behavior details? My test program assumes 32-bit ints / longs, 64-bit long longs, and "nice" two's-complement signed overflow / conversion.)

This challenge is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge); your score is determined by the total number of characters in the outputs for these ten randomly-generated inputs: (*TODO*).

**Bonus:** Subtract 15 from your score if the output expression evaluates to **1**, not just nonzero, for all 'true' inputs.

### Sandbox Questions

Welp, turns out my "[Round Fractions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/7476#7476)" question from earlier is pretty much a subset of "[Closest fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction)". So here's another idea I've been tossing around since the one challenge I answered in C a while back ([Area of an ASCII Polygon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49312/area-of-an-ascii-polygon)).

This is still very much a work-in-progress spec, though; some questions I have:

- I believe this could be tagged as C rather than C++; the only difference I'm aware of is the ternary conditional's precedence, and given that no assignment operators are allowed, it might not make a difference.
- I'm not sure what tags would go best on this (is it [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) if the output isn't fixed?)
- I imagine there should probably be some additional constraint to prevent theoretically optimal but impossibly slow brute-force searches.
- The range [1, 127] is kind of arbitrary; my thought is that it should be able to handle anything in ASCII range + whitespace characters, but not much more than that, so as to make the special cases less restrictive.
- Would there be a way to spin this off as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), if establishing run-time conditions is too arbitrary?

I'm mostly done writing a program to test the output expressions; just need to do a bit more testing.

That's pretty much it; hopefully this is enough to work with for feedback. Thoughts / comments?

Comment: Interesting challenge. I think a time-limited [tag:code-challenge] is a better fit than [tag:code-golf], because there's a lot of complexity with that many operators and golfed code would be hideous. I think the random test cases should be supplemented with some which are designed to favour different operators, so that deciding to leave some out for speed becomes a real trade-off. There's only one integer literal which anyone would want to use in octal, so you could make a special case for `0`. If you're going to allow `LL` in tokens then you really should be explicit about type widths.

Answer (score 0):

## [Quiddler](http://www.setgame.com/quiddler)

Quiddler is a card game where you try to create words from letter cards drawn from a deck. A word is defined as being more than 2 cards in length. Sometimes letters are combined on cards in this game, however that will not be the case in this challenge.

Your mission is to write a program which creates words from the letters read in on standard input. Your dictionary of words is the [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_%28Unix%29) file on any standard unix system. You may assume that all strings this file is all lowercase.

### Input

The string of letters you can use to create words is read in on standard input. This string will be all lowercase, and will not have any spaces in it.

Valid examples are:

```
actlj
jactl
ljdkj
jjabc
```

Invalid are:

```
jklKLJKKJLKUIU
klj kljklj djkas;
```

### Output

The list of all possible results from said string each string. Remember you can produce multiple words in the same answer.

Examples of valid output include. Please remember that I came up with these off the top of my head, and may not be complete. Input is left aligned and the output is presented as the indented lines. The `->` is for your benefit.

```
tacb  -> 
         cat
         act
         bat
         tab

fivquedrr ->
         five qud
         quid five
         river
         quiver
```

The order of the solutions output does not need to be in any specific order.

## The environment

This program must run in a standard UNIX-like environment. This means that you may use any standard shell (bash, ksh, csh, zsh, fish), and you have access to all the standard tools. This challenge is restricted to the shell scripting languages.

The path to the dictionary file in the environment variable, `DICT`, the path to the file should not be in any valid solution. Use `$DICT` as the path to the dictionary. This is included so that you can provide testing instructions for your program.

## Winner

The winner is the one with the fewest bytes of code that produces the correct output.

Comment: In the example output, I'm not sure why for the first input the output is newline-separated, but for the second it's space-separated. I also don't understand the second paragraph in the section "*The environment*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor In quiddler you can have multiple words per possible solution. I'll add a second example to demo.

Comment: So is this basically a variant on [Countdown](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38233/194) where the dictionary is amplified by including its Cartesian power?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Pretty much, except I did not know that existed. Also,  for each answer you can only use each answer once.

Answer (score 0):

## Cops and Robbers - Find the Formula

Cops will write a function that takes numerical inputs and produces numerical outputs (note - outputs can be any base and may contain letters). They will post the language, the number of bytes it takes to write the code (up to 128), rounded **up** to the nearest power of 2, as well as a minimum of 2 test cases. The robbers will try to write a program that takes the same numerical inputs as the test cases and produces identical outputs.

Note - PRNG's, hashing, and other forms of encryption are not allowed.

**Scoring**

*Cops (if safe)*

The floor of the product of:

- 128 divided by the power of two rounded up for the bytes
- The natural logarithm of the number of test cases

If cracked, -10 points.

*Robbers*

The floor of the quotient of

- Half the number rounded up to by the cops
- The natural logarithm of the number of test cases

Comment: Say I have a function `f(x)` that returns `x` when `x<2` and `3*x` ᴏtherwise. Would the robber's function only have to match the given test cases, or have to match _all_ test cases?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ The given test cases only.

Comment: Is there a maximum of test cases?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'm not sure if there should be. If there were, I'd say maybe 10 or 12.

Comment: I think the scoring algorithm might be a bit complex.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I want to do something that awards points depending on the number of test cases because that makes it more likely that the robber found the intended solution and is "more" right.

Comment: The cops-and-robbers lesson which everyone should have learnt by now is that built-in crypto functions should be banned because otherwise the cops have an easy time.

Comment: ^ That should include hashing and PRNGs. Although it's really hard to rule them out conclusively. My personal goal is still to come up with more CnRs that aren't susceptible to stuff like that in the first place (like my Programming Language Quiz).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Given that I've explicitly disallowed hashing, PRNGs, and encryption, what do you think of this challenge?

Comment: @Eridan It's still susceptible to arbitrary base conversions or expmod (just check out any CnR-submission by Dennis to see some examples). People can just throw together a quasi-random program in a golfing-language without having to understand it and just run some numbers through it to generate test cases.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I didn't realize those were bad for CnR challenges (I even mentioned base conversion above). Is there a specific way I could describe methods like those to disallow them?

Comment: @Eridan none I can think of. That's why I meant that this is an inherent problem of any CnR that lets participant choose what their program does. In CnRs where the programs need to solve a specific task, this is not such a big issue, because the cops actually need to find a convoluted but working implementation themselves.

Comment: Even with crypto banned, numerical functions make for boring CnR challenges since it's much more likely to be about finding parameters rather than guessing the structure of the code.

Comment: A problem: Anyone can just write an interpolating polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I think the question is fine. I just need some more testcases for it.

---

---

You are given the priority order of alleles for a particular trait. For example,

```
A B
O
```

means that `A` and `B` are equally dominant and `O` is recessive to both of them. An organism has exactly two alleles, but only the dominant trait(s) is/are expressed. So an organism with gene `AO` will express only `A` but an organism with gene `AB` will express both `A` and `B`. An organism with two same alleles will express that allele only.

Each offspring will receive two alleles - one from the mother and the other from the father. So if the initial parents are `AB` and `AO`, the offspring formed will be:

```
AA - 25%
AO - 25%
AB - 25%
BO - 25%
```

Expressed traits will be

```
A - 50%
AB - 25%
B - 25%
```

Offspring of one generation may breed only with a single member of the opposite sex in the same generation during its lifetime. Assume for the sake of this challenge that every male finds a random female in the same generation and has exactly two children - one male and one female. Siblings may interbreed. Note that, except for the first generation, we can ignore the sex of the individuals as their sex chromosomes assort independently of their other characteristics.

**Input**

- Priority order of all alleles (may include unnecesary alleles)
- Genotype of every organism in initial generation
- Number of generations created
- Any one allele
- (Optional) Number of lines of input for priority order (for languages like C++)

**Output**

- Probability of the specified allele existing in a randomly selected  individual in the specified generation (accurate to three decimal places)

**Challenge**

- Once two/three answers are posted, I'll use the same testcases in all of them to see which of them are faulty.
- After a week (or I could prolong the deadline) I will upload a lengthy test case in a few days. The code that solves it in the fastest time wins.

**Sample data** (Some simple testcases)

**#1**

```
A
B
C
Male(s) - AA
Female(s) - AB
5
C
```

Output `0`

**#2**

```
A
B
C
Male(s) - AA
Female(s) - AB
2
A
```

Output `0.75`

**#3**

```
A B
C D
Male(s) - AC,BD
Female(s) - AC,BC
1
C
```

Output `0.125`

Comment: _"Once two/three answers are posted, I'll use the same testcases in all of them to see which of them are faulty"_ You should have a way to verify answers without using other answers.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I am **abandoning** this Q, anyone else is free to post it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

## Ancient Language Translator

<insert a silly story here>

### Task:

Write a program that takes an English sentence and translates it into the [Ancient Language](http://www.paolini.net/writers-corner/invented-languages-inheritance-cycle/ancient-language/english-ancient-language-dictionary/).
You have to implement at least 42 words.
For the purpose of this challenge, you do not have to care about special rules such as "(may be shortened to al when used as a prefix, as in albitr)".

### Input:

An English sentence.

### Output:

A translated version of the input, simply replace the English words with the Ancient ones.

### Examples:

To be added.

### Scoring:

Suggestions?

Comment: This might be considered as too broad as there is no specific words to implement. For scoring a [tag:code-challenge] might work with the score being something like the sum of the length of all words implemented. [tag:code-golf] might also work. Kind of [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51109/40695) challenge. The title is also possibly misleading, so I'd suggest putting "Ancient Language" in quotes

Comment: I think this would be uninteresting just because it's just replacement, not actual translation.

Comment: @sysreq Translating English into the "Ancient Language" is just replacement as far as I know...

Comment: @Downgoat Oh, ok! So, what words should have to be included? A selection of) the most common words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English

Answer (score 0):

## Simple ASCII Representation of a Screw Head

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Inputs are a string and a number.

If the string is "Slot", the number will be 0, 60, 90, or 120. If the number is 0, output `--`; if 60, output `/`; if 90, output `|`, if 120, output `\`.

If the string is "Phillips", the number will be 0, 45, 90, or 135. If it's 0 or 90, output `+`; otherwise output `x`.

If the string is "Torx", the number will be 0, 60, or 120. Regardless of the value, output `*`.

If the string is "Spanner", the number will be 0 or 90. Output `..` for 0 and `:` for 90.

Behavior for all other inputs is undefined.

[Is this challenge too simple? If so, could more test cases help?]

Comment: I think adding test cases that require modular division (so you could say `Phillips 72270`) and error handling (`GenericScrewXyz 43` would throw an error).

Answer (score 0):

## Nested Header List

The goal of this challenge is to complete a list of consecutive nested header numbers when given a start and an end.  When given `1.1.1` and `1.1.5` you should generate `1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5`

**Specific Rules**

1. Your entry must take in a `start`, `end`, and multiple optional `range` parameters.  Parameters can be taken form STDIN (or nearest equivalent) or a file.
2. Your entry may assume valid input
3. Input will be of the following format:

   1. `start` and `end` will be strings of `.` delimited integers of the same length
   2. `start` and `end` will have three segments; (1) set values, (2) iterator, (3) trailing values.

      - The iterator is the first value which differs between `start` and `end`.
      - The set values are the values before the iterator.  These values never change
      - The trailing values are the values after the iterator.  These values iterate up as determined by the `range` parameter(s). **All trailing values will be `1`**.
   3. `range` will be a list of integers with a length corresponding to the number of trailing values.  When there are no trailing values, `range` is not specified. The value of `range` corresponding to each trailing value determines the *inclusive upper bound* which that entry iterates to.
4. Output will be to STDOUT (or closest alternative) and will show each value separated by at least one delimiter.  Delimiter can by any character or string of characters, but it must be consistent. Output must be sorted correctly

**Examples**

```
start = '1.1.5.1', end = '1.1.6.1', range = [5]
Output: 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.1.5.3, 1.1.5.4, 1.1.5.5, 1.1.6.1
                                                  ^
                                                  previous value is iterated
                                                  only when iterating value
                                                  limit set by range


start = '1.1.5.1', end = '1.1.7.1', range = [5]
Output: 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.1.5.3, 1.1.5.4, 1.1.5.5, 1.1.6.1,
        1.1.6.1, 1.1.6.2, 1.1.6.3, 1.1.6.4, 1.1.6.5, 1.1.7.1

start = '1.5.1.1', end = '1.6.1.1', range = [5,2]
Output: 1.5.1.1, 1.5.1.2, 1.5.2.1, 1.5.2.2, 1.5.3.1, 1.5.3.2, 
        1.5.4.1, 1.5.4.2, 1.5.5.1, 1.5.5.2, 1.6.1.1
```

This is code golf so shortest code by bytes wins.

**Bonuses**

1. Allow trailing values to be values other than `1` in `end` parameter - **12.5% off**
2. Handle incorrect number of values in `range` parameter - **12.5% off**
3. Handle `end` less than `start` by producing list in reverse - **50% off**

Answer (score 0):

## Count the Connect Four Positions

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Connect Four is a two-player game on a rectangular board. The board is `m` spaces wide and `n` spaces tall, and players alternate placing pieces in columns. A placed piece always fills the lowest empty space in a column, and a player may not move in a full column. In the standard game, m=7 and n=6.

The game ends when one player completes a row of four pieces vertically, horizontally, or diagonally, or all `m` columns are full. The edges of the board do not wrap.

### Challenge

Write a program or function to determine the number of distinct, legal `m` by `n` Connect Four boards after `p` plies. (A ply is one move by one player.) A legal position is one reachable from the empty board through a sequence of moves in which no player had already won. (A position in which one player has just won is legal.)

### Rules

You may assume that `0<=p<=m*n`, `m<=8` and `n<=8`.

As usual, hardcoding is not allowed.

Your code should be at most 1024 bytes in length, and use at most 16 GB of memory.

Related: [Determine winner of Connect 4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63603/39328)

### Test cases

[need to add; include OEIS]

Relevant links:

- [This Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301106/how-many-different-game-situations-has-connect-four%5D)
- [This offsite page](https://tromp.github.io/c4/c4.html)
- [OEIS sequence for n=7, m=6](https://oeis.org/A212693)

Answer (score 0):

## Compile *from* Brainfuck

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The professors at Brainfuck University realized their jobs are horrible, because all they do is discuss quantum mechanics using Brainfuck, so they decided to take their programs and compile them to a better language. Because of the randomness of quantum particles, their program needs to be small so it has a smaller chance of being disrupted in the Higgs Field.

Your task is to get a Brainfuck program from any input and output that program transcompiled into another language. Here is an example:

```
++-->><<
```

Compiles to the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char *cell = calloc(30000, 1);
    unsigned char *cells = cell;
    if (!cell) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }
        //actual program
        ++*cell;
        ++*cell;
        --*cell;
        --*cell;
        --cell;
        --cell;
        ++cell;
        ++cell;

        free(cells);
        return 0;
}
```

### Score

Your score is the size of your program added to the size of the output.

#### Bonuses

- If you support [Brainfuck-ng](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck-ng), subtract **30**

Comment: [Dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19899/write-a-brainfuck-translator)

Answer (score 0):

**Logic Puzzle Solver/Inference Engine**

Your goal is to take the clues and other facts given in a grade-school logic grid puzzle such as [these](http://www.edhelperblog.com/cgi-bin/vocab.cgi?FORMMODE=OO&WS=2) and solve the puzzle. To keep things simple, your program will only solve specific logic problems about which it can make the assumptions you wish to hard-code in, but the program need not perform any checks to see if those assumptions can be made.

**You may not use:**

- A declarative language
- Any function provided - by an external dependency - for the solving of a logic puzzle.

**Input**

Your program will take input from the command line. After gathering assumptions, the program will ask for facts written as such:

```
subject.verb object
```

for all true facts. For false facts:

```
!subject.verb object
```

Examples: If Chad bought donuts,

```
Chad.bought donuts
```

If he didn't:

```
!Chad.bought donuts.
```

If Nancy's last name isn't Wesley,

```
!Nancy.is Wesley.
```

**Output**

Your program will output its conclusions as such:

```
subject verb object.
```

So, if your program determines that Chad bought donuts and Nancy's last name is Wesley, then it will output:

```
Chad bought donuts.

Nancy's last name is Wesley.
```

Comment: The "these" link goes to a login page. I'm not going to create an account on some random site just to find out what the spec is.

Comment: "*You may not use a declarative language*" :-(

Comment: Does "is" always refer to someone's last name? If not, how can our code know the difference between Nancy.is Wesley and Nancy.is chef?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about a challenge on wrapping time.

I am a member here for 34 days now. I would have expected for the date to wrap to 1 month.

#### Rules:

- starting with hours from the joining date to now.
- first wrapping happens when you go over 24 hours, the count will be in days now.
- second wrapping happens after reaching 30 or 31 days, you can decide, to months.
- third wrapping really wraps when a year is reached, it shall be displayed as i.e. 2 years 3 month.
- round to neares full unit, i.e. 43 days = 1 month, 50 days = 2 month
- take either a build in function to get the current time or hardcode it to ´2015-12-19-11´ <- time when challenge will be posted. If hardcoding it is shorter you may take the bytecount from the hardcoded version.
- Dates after the current or hardcoded date can do whatever.

#### Input

The joining date and hour like ´YYYY-MM-DD-HH´ the delimeter does not have to be a - choose whatever you like.

#### Output

The time according to the rules above.

#### Example:

```
In: 2015-12-10
Out: 9 Days

In: 2015-10-28
Out: 2 Month
```

Comment: I believe I saw a challenge about wrapping 24-hour time that may be related, but not a duplicate. Also, what date are we calculating the difference from?

Comment: that would be the date right now or a set date if no build in is available

Comment: I think it should be either a built-in date or another date given from input for all languages, to make things fair.

Comment: I wanted it to be non input, how would you suggest doing that?

Comment: Use a built-in date such as `01-01-2015` (or `01-01-2000`, depending on what the date range should be). The program should not be required to accept dates before that.

Answer (score 0):

**New user to Programming Puzzles!**

***Spades CHALLENGE!!!***

I would like a king of the hill challenge for bots playing the game of spades.  Spades is a card game.  The rules are shown on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spades).

**Scoring rules:**

- Nils allowed, with 50 points for completion (not 100).  -50 for losing.
- 10 points a hand, with sandbagging allowed.
- Partnership Playing
- Sum of all four players hands cannot equal 13!

Winner is first to 500 points.  The bot will be paired with all other bots entered into the competition.  The pair of winners will be crowned with +10 meta-points (Mpoints), losers will get -1 Mpoints. Whoever has the most Mpoints wins - ties based upon sum of points earned in the games.

**Gameplay:**

- The bot with the lowest Mpoints bids first.  Bidding proceeds from down until reaching 4th slot, then goes back to first slot and continues.  Play starts with this player.
- The bot will be given a string of cards - AS for Ace of Spades, JC for Jack of Clubs, 2D for 2 of Diamonds, 8H for 8 of hearts, randomly dealt from a single 52-card deck.  Each will be comma separated: *AS,JC,2D,8H,4C,5S,8D,3D,3S,JS,10S*
- The bot will get the bids from the other bots before making the bid.
- Upon winning a hand, the bot gets to continue making plays until someone else wins the hand.
- Hands are scored at the end using the scoring rules.  If a team's score is less than 500, gameplay continues with a new hand.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to setup the servers or any of that stuff.  I just think the challenge will be interesting.  If anyone can help with that, run with it.  I like to watch these challenges unfold - but I'm too much of an engineer and not enough of a programmer to make these kinds of programming happen.

Comment: You should fully list out the rules in the body of the question - it's considered poor form for challenges to require exterior resources to be fully understood.

Answer (score 0):

## Browser identifier

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

There are three major browsers at the moment, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Firefox. Sometimes, the JavaScript engines inside of these browsers work a bit differently, and that can break some applications. Therefore, we need a way to identify what browser the user is currently using!

Your answer should be a JavaScript program or function, that when run on the latest version of a browser, should output a string representing that browser. The string outputed could be anything, as long as it stays the same every time you run it. Output should go to a HTML paragraph with id `O`, `console.log`, or as return value.

Please put your answer in a snippet, along with `<p id="o"></p>` in the HTML section if your answer uses it.

*(scoreboard snippet goes here)*

Comment: I believe Javascript has a builtin for this. It may be best to forbid using it.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Well, I did some searching before, and I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript) thread on SO, and the highest voted answer was a big mess, and no answer was very short and reliable. There is [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser), and it has some that could be golfed a bit, but there isn't really one function / builtin that checks the browser.

Comment: You might need to freeze the version numbers of the 3 browsers, or else require that answers specify version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Nth Regex

This challenge('s explanation) is simple: given a number `n` and a regex `r`, output the `n`th string that matches `r`!

The regex `r` uses the syntax used in Python, [described here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). The regex will be for the whole string, meaning the regex will be implicitly wrapped in `^$`.

The only valid strings are printable ASCII characters, and they count up like base 95 (ASCII codes 32-126).

To prevent people from brute-forcing it, I was thinking of making it [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).

Comment: I still think you mean "bijective base 95". otherwise, there are no strings with leading spaces (because if count up in base 10, there are no numbers with leading zeroes).

Comment: I'm not a fan of using a specific real-world flavour, because that gives an advantage to Python over all other languages. I also think it contains way too many features to be fun to tackle (which don't really add anything interesting to the challenge). I think the challenge would be interesting and hard enough for a simplified regex flavour containing only simple quantifiers, alternation and character classes.

Comment: I'm quite sure that some regexes are hard to solve. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39829/cops-and-robbers-regex-golf/39950#39950

Comment: I absolutely don't get the challenge, any example input/output ?

Comment: Do you mean nth string lexicographically?

Answer (score 0):

## Parse a tree for pruning

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Windows supplies users with `tree`: a neat little tool that converts a directory tree to ASCII-CP437 art. It's a very human-readable format. However, it's a bit useless if you want the directory tree of an entire drive, or even just the Windows folder, as it's very hard to prune the parts you don't want. Hence this challenge.

### Task

Your task is to produce a function or program that will convert the tree from one or both of the input formats into one or more of the output formats. The smaller your code, the more of a head start you have.

### Input

There are two types of input that you might be given:

#### CP437

This is the default.

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Main Drive
Volume serial number is 00F3-F586
C:\WINDOWS
│   explorer.exe
│   notepad.exe
│   virus.dll
│   WLXPGSS.SCR
│   write.exe
│   
├───Boot
│   │   BootDebuggerFiles.ini
│   │   
│   ├───DVD
│   │       your.txt
│   │       
│   ├───EFI
│   │       pc.txt
│   │       
│   ├───Fonts
│   │       has.txt
│   │       
│   ├───PCAT
│   │       been.txt
│   │       
│   └───Resources
│           wrecked.txt
│           
├───System
└───System32
        cmd.exe
        conhost.exe
        winlogon.cmd
        winlogon.exe
```

#### ASCII

This will be easier to parse for many languages.

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Main Drive
Volume serial number is 00F3-F586
C:\WINDOWS
|   explorer.exe
|   notepad.exe
|   virus.dll
|   WLXPGSS.SCR
|   write.exe
|   
+---Boot
|   |   BootDebuggerFiles.ini
|   |   
|   +---DVD
|   |       your.txt
|   |       
|   +---EFI
|   |       pc.txt
|   |       
|   +---Fonts
|   |       has.txt
|   |       
|   +---PCAT
|   |       been.txt
|   |       
|   \---Resources
|           wrecked.txt
|           
+---System
\---System32
        cmd.exe
        conhost.exe
        winlogon.cmd
        winlogon.exe
```

### Output

There are several possible types of output you can return, each suited to a different type of language.

#### Array / List hierarchy of strings

The first element of each array / list is the name, the rest are the contents. Files should be represented by strings, empty folders should be represented by a single-length array containing one string. Note: This should be returned from a function as an array / list, not printed as a string.

```
["C:\WINDOWS", "explorer.exe", "notepad.exe", "virus.dll", "WLXPGSS.SCR", "write.exe", ["Boot", "BootDebuggerFiles.ini", ["DVD", "your.txt"], ["EFI", "pc.txt"], ["Fonts", "has.txt"], ["PCAT", "been.txt"], ["Resources", "wrecked.txt"]], ["System"], ["System32", "cmd.exe", "conhost.exe", "winlogon.cmd", "winlogon.exe"]]
```

#### Object / Dictionary

Similar to array / list, but a little more intuitive. Folders should have the value of their contents as another object / dictionary. Files should have the value "FILE".

```
{"C:\WINDOWS":{"explorer.exe":"FILE","notepad.exe":"FILE","virus.dll":"FILE","WLXPGSS.SCR":"FILE","write.exe":"FILE","Boot":{"BootDebuggerFiles.ini":"FILE","DVD":{"your.txt":"FILE"},"EFI":{"pc.txt":"FILE"},"Fonts":{"has.txt":"FILE"} [...] } [...] } [...] }
```

#### Lisp-style string

Similar to array / list, where the head of the list is the directory name and the tail is the contents. An empty directory is a list with no tail, and a file is a string.

```
No WAY am I putting an example. No way. I've spent half the time on this question creating the examples. No way. Ok, maybe later.
```

#### Bonus

If you satisfy none of these bonuses, your submission is still valid. But its score shall infinite, so it is non-competitive.
These bonuses are to multiply your score by. Bonuses stack by multiplication. These bonuses must all be achieved consistently to be awarded.

- 100% Allow at least one input mode and output mode
- 50% Allow both input modes
- 90% Output in exactly two ways
- 50% Output in one of two ways depending on parameters
- 80% Output in exactly three ways
- 25% Output in one of three ways depending on parameters

Answer (score 0):

## Identifying spies in "[Resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Resistance_(game))"

*This is still very rough, but I think it has the makings of an interesting challenge. Please help me improve it. What do I need to add? What do I need clarify?*

Resistance is a party game that pits "resistance members" against "imperial spies" on a series of missions. A very important aspect of the game is that the resistance members do not know who the spies are, whereas the spies do know who is who.

**How the game works**

The relevant details of the game will be added here. For now, just check the Wikipedia page linked in the title.

**Challenge**

your challenge is to write a program that takes as input the details of every round and outputs who it thinks is a spy after each round. There are 5 rounds (missions) in a game of resistance, so the program/function will take in all the data for the first round, which includes

1. Each proposed team to go on the mission
2. Each public vote following each proposal
3. The final team to go on the mission
4. The outcome of the mission (i.e. how many passes and how many fails)

It will then output who it thinks is a spy. It will then do the same for each subsequent round.

**Important Details**

*We will be playing resistance for (6?) people,* A, B, C, D, E, *and* F.

*Input format is flexible*. It may be done round by round or all at once. However, since ach submission is outputting something for each of the five rounds, the submission may not use information from future rounds (if all information is given at once) in judging the current round.

Here is an example of possible input format:

Since the first mission requires two people, and person A is the first mission planner, the only thing input would be two letters in {A,B,C,D,E,F} indicating his selection. Then the votes of each person, in order, would be input. This continues until a mission team is accepted. Then the votes given on the mission would be input, in no/any particular order. The program would then output the letters of the two people it thinks are spies (there are 2 spies in a 6 person game). Here is an example

```
A B              # A selects A and B for first mission
P P P F F F      # Everyone votes, mission team is not accepted (lacks majority pass)
B F              # B selects B and F for first mission
P P P P P F      # Mission team is accepted (majority pass)
P F              # Mission fails (there is at least one fail vote). Note that the order does not matter here.
```

The bot would then output two people, the people it thinks are most likely to be the spies based on all the information it has up to this point.

```
B F              # Any two person subset is acceptable
```

Input then continues for the next 4 rounds, until the game is over.

**Scoring**

I will write several hundred test cases (from actual games played online). Then each output will be scored in the following way:

- 1 point for each correctly guessed spy.
- 1 point for guessing both spies correctly.

The submission's total score will be the sum of all scores on all rounds in all games. The program will never be told who is a spy (unless it is used to self-score and does not factor into the actual guessing) but this information will be available with the test cases for scoring purposes.

Tie break is code golf.

---

Meta: I think I'm going to remove output after the first round, because very rarely do people ever fail the first mission. So it will likely just be pure chance.

Answer (score 0):

## Everything about PI

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Pi is the most popular transcedental number. As a result, pi has been thoroughly studied. This challenge is in spirit of 9-Hole challenge.

### 1. Digits of PI

Given n and k, output n'th digit after the decimal point in the base-k representation. For example, the 5th digit of PI base 10 is 9.

```
5 10
9
10 2
0
6 16
10
```

If the base is more than 10, output like in the last test case

More information : http://www.virtuescience.com/pi-in-other-bases.html

### 2. Continued fraction of PI

Given n, output n'th number in continued fraction of Pi.

```
5
292
7
1
```

### 3. Closest to PI

Given a positive integer `d`, output the integer `n` such that `n/d` is closest to pi. For example, `17/5` is closer to pi than any other `n/5`.

```
 5
 17
 7
 22
 21
 66
```

### 4. Closest to PI 2

Given a positive integer `n`, output the integer `d` such that `n/d` is closest to pi.

```
5
2
7
2
20
6
```

## Restriction.

1. You should not have any floating-number buildin, only integer, including PI constants.
2. Standard loophole is disallowed.
3. The program may be 4 program or a program that reads challenge number.

## Sandbox Question

Originally, I have 5 challenge, 4 more required. Now, one of them is dupe. 5 more required.

Comment: This does look suspiciously like lot of questions rolled into one. +1 and you could split it up into loads of challenges.

Comment: Also, you could add more clarification on what a "9-Hole challenge" is.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16707/46245

Comment: The spirit is more than one challenge in one question.

Comment: Are you looking for 4 more sub-challenges, or a catchy name for a 5 component question?

Comment: *Quint*essential pi question?

Comment: A. I believe that the "many small holes in one question" model is considered  a failed experiment. B. I don't understand the spec for part 1 at all. Part 2 is inadequately specified. Part 3 is a [dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4227/194). Parts 4 and 5 look almost completely trivial (or completely trivial for languages with a pi built-in).

Comment: Added that pi build-in is not allowed

Comment: What about getting pi via inverse trig? Complex logs? Evaluating integrals? Banning the built in value still lets languages express it via math, and it's tricky to draw the line.

Comment: Also, why does every question need to use pi? If you want a challenge about, say, rational approximations, you can use arbitrary inputs or square roots or anything all langs have access to roughly equally.

Comment: @xnor 1. trigonometry, log, etc. is useless without floating point number. And any uses of floating point number isn't allowed (Even if it just uses addition only). However, I am afraid of integrals, too. 2. Just because.

Comment: In the revised version, I think that if these were posted separately then part 1 would be closed as a dupe of part 3. Also, part 2 is still inadequately specified. You need to at minimum explain the indexing convention, and ideally specify what a continued fraction is (since some answers may use generalised continued fractions and confuse people who aren't familiar with them).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't understand how part 1 is dupe of part 3. For part 2 I uses simple continued fraction and what is indexing convention?

Comment: A. Part 3 says "Given `d`, find `n` such that  `(n-0.5)/d < pi < (n+0.5)/d`". Part 1 is essentially (since there isn't a general Plouffe formula for all bases) "Given `k` and `n`, find `b` such that `b / k^n < pi < (b+1) / k^n` and then return `b % k`". The core problem is almost identical. B. It's not enough for you to know that you're using simple continued fractions: the question has to make it clear. The indexing convention is whether you count the initial `3 + ...` as index `0` or `1`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor A. The insight clears my mind. Thanks. I don't think as far as that. B. 1. But I don't know how to explain that. Please add yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**How to print 2016 using only the number 2?**

Print `2016` using only the digit 2 operators and native language built-in functions.

The objective is to

- Output the integer `2016` without using any digits except 2.
- no characters / strings literals are allowed, i.e. no tricks like `ord('b')`
- The code that uses the least number of 2s in the code wins.

For example, in python, the following code uses 8 twos.:

```
>>> int(str(2**2*2) + str(2**2)) * int(str(2) + str(2**2))
2016
```

Or like this code, uses 13 twos:

```
>>> 2 ** 2 ** 2 * 2 ** 2 ** 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 2 ** 2 ** 2 * 2
2016
```

Comment: Can you use constants initialized to a certain value (like CJam's `Z` variable which defaults to `3`)?

Comment: What's the tiebreaker if multiple answers have the same number of `2`s?

Comment: 1. Every language that has variables will have a score of at most 1, since you can just save the initial **2** in a variable. 2. There are many ways to produce numbers without using characters, strings or other numbers, like taking the length of a list, for example. That means a score of 0 is just as easy.

Comment: I would suggest making the scoring system a normal [tag:code-golf] challenge and disallowing date functions.

Comment: I will make my original suggestion again: require that every function and operator take as input either a number consisting entirely of 2's in some base, or the output of some function or operator that obeys this rule. If you insist on your "least number of 2's metric" count 2's passed inside variables or in the outputs of functions as contributing to this count.

Comment: What about such version: In repl environment produce value 2016 using only number 2, operators and math functions. No any other functions allowed. Code golf or code challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Growing Quine 2

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Your task is to give program P1..P5 so that.

1. For all k<5, length of Pk < length of Pk+1
2. For all k<5, Pk outputs Pk+1
3. For all k<=5, Pk is semi-pristine program. (Program that if any run on the source-code is deleted, will output different output)
4. P5 return P1 sufficient times that the output will be longer than P5

Shortest P1 wins

Comment: By rule 4, do you mean if P1 is `abc`, then the output should be `abcabcabc...` for the minimum amount of repetitions that is longer than P5? can we output it more often that necessary? Also, I think rule 3 makes this incredibly hard.

Comment: First, Yes. The rule 3 is to prevent the padding of source code with nop. Maybe I will change into different output to make this easier.

Comment: I mean rule 4 can repeat more often than necessary

Answer (score 0):

## War of Flatland

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

If you haven't read [Flatland](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Ebanchoff/Flatland/), please do so here. It is a must-read, for mathematical and non-mathematical alike.

Oh no. No no no! War has broken out in [Flatland](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Ebanchoff/Flatland/). Society has crumbled, and all the women and children are either hiding or dead<sup>1</sup>. It is total anarchy, kill or be killed. It is such conflict that the 4th dimensional people have erected indestructible borders to prevent the conflict spreading.

On the plus side, if you came out on top, you could rule (some of) the entire world!

### Specifications

- You can be a shape with three or more sides. (No women<sup>1</sup>, remember?)
- All shapes are regular.
- You can only see by sight. (No feeling; you'll be killed if you get close enough to do that!)
- Everybody starts with 1 health.
- You can hurt other people by stabbing one of their edges with a vertex.
- The vertex of an `n` sided shape deals `1/n` damage.
- An `n` sided shape has `4n` angles of vision (sensors evenly spaced around the shape which see the nearest point and return the distance to it).
- An `n` sided shape can see `2n` different distances (range [`[0,16)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals))
- People don't see themselves. (What good is sight if your body gets in the way?)
- People are all the same size (radius).
- People can see everything within 16 units of their centre point.
- If your health is `0` or below, you are killed.
- The world has borders.
- You can rotate by a maximum of `15` degrees either direction, then move exactly 1 unit towards either of your vertices every turn.
- Each shape's "radius" is 8 units.
- Degrees are anticlockwise from 3 O'clock. The 0th sensor is at 3 O'clock relative to the shape's orientation.

<sup>1</sup> This is not me being sexist. Read [Flatland](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Ebanchoff/Flatland/).

## Sandbox Meta:

I am using the Sandbox as a public incubator. I will build up and work on the challenge until it is ready, then post it as a question. But it made more sense to let others see, comment on and help with this challenge's development.

The Specifications are probably not going to remain in this format once the Stack Snippet and actual code is up and running.
I am working on, and have got quite far with, a JavaScript class to let people write code. If anyone can write a code to do the <sub><sup>boring</sup></sub> rendering thing onto a HTML5 canvas, I would be grateful.

#### Stuff I plan to add:

- A stack-snippet battlefield
- A JavaScript class to let people write code
- A web-socket system to let people make submissions in other languages
- A system to pull submissions from answers (I'm no good at this sort of thing)

Comment: 1. What counts as stabbing an edge? (I can see the numerical issues involved in working out whether a contact is vertex-vertex or edge-vertex being quite hairy). 2. What does it mean that "*an `n` sided shape has `4n` angles of vision*"? 3. How does movement work?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. I calculate line intersections on shapes with close enough centres, then I count the intersections and work out where the intersections are. 2. First, read up on how Flatlanders see distance. Distance is represented by a number. You have `4n` numbers, evenly spaced around the shape. So a triangle will have 12 angles of vision. 3. You can rotate by a maximum of `undecided` degrees and move 1 unit towards either of your vertices every turn.

Comment: The word *distance* occurs only 9 times in [the text](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~banchoff/Flatland/), and none of them seem to address how distance is perceived per se.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Part 1 Chapter 5

Comment: Why not just say that vision extends out to 16 units and that each movement is 1 unit? Other considerations: what prevents a player from repeatedly stabbing another one? If everyone moves the same distance in a turn, I don't see how escape is possible. Do people/bots choose how many sides they have? It seems to me like a triangle would be the best choice. The only downside is fewer sensors, but I don't think that's a particularly bad one.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I've been trying to make higher shapes more balanced. And hopefully there will be a defined bouncing mechanism after stabbing. (Spinning like a saw however...) And yes, they choose.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman what if you always start as a triangle, a vertex forms on a side whenever one gets stabbed there (like a bruise swelling up). Or, in other words, an n-gon becomes an n+1-gon when stabbed. Stabs don't do ANY damage other than this. You die when n exceeds some threshold. This seems self-balancing: The more vertices you have the more people you can poke at once and the sooner you can poke them (because you already have a vertex aimed at them).

Comment: Another balancing possibility is making higher-sided shapes move faster.

Comment: @quintopia But that is simply a balancing system, and is in no way derived from the book. (But will probably be used if nobody can think of another way to balance the higher shapes that is derived from the book).

Comment: I was purposefully avoiding letting the content of the book influence my recommendations. It's more important that the game is fun than that it's thematic.

Comment: @quintopia I suppose... But your speed idea would introduce the issue of how fast? Would it be logarithmic? Would there be a point where it is unrealistic to be able to kill a higher-sided shape because they can practically teleport?

Comment: @quintopia And the `n=>n+1` idea is a completely different challenge!

Answer (score 0):

## Zipping double quine.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

You must provide 2 program, A and B. Both are a quine and have same length.

If A and B is zipped each other(Both when A is zipped first, or B is zipped first), the result is also an quine.

Standard Loopholes is not allowed and standard quine rules apply.

### Examples

If program A is `ABCDEF` and program B is `GHIJKL` then

```
slangi "ABCDEF"
ABCDEF
slangi "GHIJKL"
GHIJKL
slangi "AGBHCIDJEKFL"
AGBHCIDJEKFL
slangi "GAHBICJDKELF"
GAHBICJDKELF
```

Comment: Do all three quines have to use the same language? Are function quines allowed?

Comment: @Dennis All three quine have to use same language. Function quines is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Print as many numbers as you can

A [restricted-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-code) challenge where you have two occurrences of each ASCII character from 20 to 7E to write as many programs as you can to print single distinct integers (one integer per program). For example, you cannot have `A` and `AA` to print `10` and `1010` in CJam, respectively, as that is three occurrences of `A`.

Full programs are not required.

You get 1 point for each integer you print. In the case that two answers create the same number of integers, the tiebreaker is the answer that uses the fewest bytes to create the integers.

Is this a good idea for a challenge? Also, is it a dupe? I feel like I've seen it before but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1. `TT` is an odd example here, since it would print `10\n10` in Pyth. `AA` prints `1010` in CJam. 2. Are full programs required? Are leading zeroes allowed? Can the integers be negative?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the scoring, would we get to pick our own integer? And in your example, would `AA` count for two points? If so I think most answers would be something like `BC#D#E#F#{A}*` in CJam, where they just output the number a million billion times in a loop. (Don't try this online..)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I added how it would be scored. The example you have would be I avoid anyways as it contains more than 2 `#` characters.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't stop people from generating giant numbers in other ways, or even infinite loops. I think a better approach would be to count the total number of programs that print exactly the same number exactly once with the same restriction. I do think this is a neat idea, but I don't think optimizing for the largest numeric output is nearly as interesting.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The challenge isn't to optimize the largest number; it's to make the greatest *quantity* of numbers.

Comment: Yes, but they are really the same thing. If I can make a large number I can print a lot of numbers.

Comment: But can you make large numbers with multiple programs (remember that you can only print one integer at a time and only have 2 of each printable ASCII character to write all your programs)?

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking about, if each program is limited to 1 point I think it's fine, that just didn't seem very clear to me, especially because of the `AA` example.

Comment: `1..99` in PowerShell will print a bunch of numbers (and similar in other languages). Is each program limited to *only* printing one? I think that's what you're intending, but it's not super-clear in your post.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you give an example? And how about character outside 20 - 7E?

Answer (score 0):

#### Print Euler's number on its own graph

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Print the first `n` characters of [Euler's number (`e`, 2.718281828459...)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) on a 'graph' of `e^n`. For example, input `3` (the x and y-axis scales here are provided for reference, and need not be implemented in your program):

```
20 |         1
19 |
18 |
17 |
16 |
15 |
14 |
13 |
12 |
11 |
10 |
 9 |
 8 |
 7 |     7
 6 |
 5 |
 4 |
 3 | 2
 2 |
 1 |
 0 | - - - - - - -
     1   2   3
      digit #
```

In the example above, note that:

- Three digits of Euler's number are presented
- Each digit is shown at a height equal to `e^n`, where `n` is the digit number. `2`, for example, is shown at height `3` because `e^1 = 2.72`, which we round up to 3. You may round up or down, see below.

Various other informational bits:

- Rounding need not be implemented; `271` is acceptable output for input `3`, as is `272`.
- You will always be provided with input >= 1 , and your input will never contain decimal places nor any characters other than 0-9.
- You may round the y value up or down, I.e. `e^3 = 20.0855` may be shown as y=20 or y=21.
- Your graph must have higher y-values at the top and higher x-values to the right; it must have a positive slope
- You may use any amount of horizontal spacing >= 1 between successive digits. In the example above, there are 3 spaces between successive digits. You just can't have digits stacked on top of eachother.
- You are not required to print scales on the x or y axis.
- Your input will always be `<= 10`.
- You may hardcode the required digits if you so desire.

Comment: You should specify about trailing and leading whitespace, on each line and before and after the graph.

Answer (score 0):

## Find my way

*I wanted to propose a challenge that is code golf (shortest answer wins), but with more programming challenge than parsing and printing funky text.  Let's see if it sticks.*

You are given a maze map, such as this:

```
#################################################
##########                    ######  ##### 1 ###
####   ##   ######  ########  #####     ####  ###
##   ###   #######  ########   ######  ###    ###
## X  ##  ########  #####      ####   #####  ##  
#                      ##      ##    ##      ##  
###################   ####   #####   #   ##  ##  
###   #############  #####   ######  #  ##   ####
##   ###             ##      ##    ##   ##     ##
#   ##      ####     ##  #   #   #      ###    ##
#  ####              ##      #   #  #        ####
#   #####   ###    ####   #####  #  #############    
#  #####   #####  ####   ##  ##     #############
   ###             ##     #  #     ########      
   ##     ####    #####   ####     ########   ###
  ##     ###                ##        #####   ###
          #####################   #   #####      
#####       ##############  ##   ###    #########
##      #   ###     ######  ##    #   ###########
#########        #               ##########      
      ###   ###     ##   ##################      
      ###   ##########   ########################
#################################################
```

and you need to help the player `1` find the goal `X`. You can assume the following rules apply to the input map:

- it is a `n x m` ASCII rectangle (i.e. `n` lines of `m` characters);
- only the following characters are allowed: `#`, `1`, `X`,  (whitespace) and newline;
- `#` represent walls (that can't be crossed),  represent empty space (that can be crossed); you can go anywhere in the `n x m` rectangle but you can't leave it (it's not Pacman).

**If the maze has a solution**, you shall produce an output of the following form:

```
#################################################
##########DLLLLLLLLL          ######  ##### D ###
####   ## D ###### U########  #####     ####D ###
##   ### DL####### U########   ######  ###  D ###
## X  ## D######## U#####      ####   ##### D##  
#  ULLLLLL         UL  ##      ##    ##     D##  
################### U ####   #####   #   ## D##  
###   ############# U#####   ######  #  ##  D####
##   ###  RRRRRRRRRRU##      ##    ##   ##  D  ##
#   ##    U ####     ##  #   #   #DLLLL ### D  ##
#  ####   U          ##      #   #D # ULLLLLL####
#   ##### U ###    ####   #####  #D #############    
#  #####RRU#####  ####   ##  ##  DL #############
   ###  U          ##     #  #  DL ########      
   ##   U ####    #####   ####DLL  ########   ###
  ##RRRRU###                ##RRD     #####   ###
    ULLLLL##################### D #   #####      
#####    U  ##############  ##  D###    #########
##      #U  ### DLL ######  ##DLL #   ###########
#########ULLLLLLL#ULLLLLLLLLLLL  ##########      
      ###   ###     ##   ##################      
      ###   ##########   ########################
#################################################
```

where:

- the letters `U`, `R`, `D` and `L` represent movements by 1 character to the, respectively, up, right, down and left;
- the letter chain represent a valid path from the original `1` (which has been replaced by a direction character) and `X`.

**If the maze has no solution**, you should return `void`, `NULL` or anything equivalent.

Final rules:

- this is code golf, so the shortest solution wins;
- typical code-golf rules for input and output apply.

Comment: This is near enough to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42707/can-maze-be-solved that I'd call it a duplicate

Comment: Your solution is odd:  It is not the shortest path.

Comment: @NathanMerrill: that was to illustrate that producing an optimal solution wasn't required

Comment: @quintopia: the example you mention can be solved with a basic flood-fill. Returning a valid path is slightly more complicated in terms of algorithm and vastly more complicated in terms of generating the output (but it's also more pleasant to look at).

Comment: @AlexandreHalm I misread. I thought yours was to output a truthy also. (However, yours can be solved with a flood fill also, with only a small amount extra effort to remove the blocked paths.)

Comment: @AlexandreHalm Speaking of which: what of mazes with multiple solutions? Since you do not require a path to be the shortest, would an output that includes all possible paths be valid?

Comment: I'm not sure enumerating multiple possible solutions would be interesting. I could require to produce the shortest path, which would make it more challenging (but even then you're not guaranteed to have a unique optimal solution). Then, unless you're willing to try some super-exponential search, you'd have to implement something like A*

Comment: To find *any* valid path requires something like backtracking algorithm. That could take a long time on any decent size maze (doing it double ended would help somewhat.) I think asking for the shortest possible is too much, unless the mazes are kept extremely simple. So I think it's more interesting as it is. But you should include wording similar to your reply to Nathan Merrill in the challenge text. Note that your text "shortest solution wins" is ambiguous (could be misinterepreted as shortest path through maze) and would be best changed to "shortest code wins."

Answer (score 0):

## Iterating through Doubles

This challenge is relatively simple:  **You are passed two floating point numbers, `a` and `b`; you must print every floating point in between *in order***.

- I don't care if your output includes `a` or `b`.  You can choose to include/exclude them if you wish.  For my examples, I will include `a`, but exclude `b`.
- You can assume that `a <= b`
- You should use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point numbers.  As to the format of the numbers, I do not care, though I will be using binary32 in my examples.
- Your program must not print any NaNs, infinities, or print out the same number twice.  `-0` is the same as `0`.
- If`a` or `b` cannot be perfectly represented in floating point, you must round-to-nearest them (standard for most languages).  You can assume that `a` and `b` won't round to infinity.
- Your program must have a runtime of `O(N)`, where `N` is the total number of floating point numbers in between `a` and `b`.
- Your program must not use more than `O(1)` storage.  The only exception to this is for storing your output before printing it all.
- Builtins that are able to generate floats in order are not allowed (such as Julia's `nextfloat()`)

For the following examples, I have used [this webpage](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to generate the numbers, and thus my examples may have human errors.

```
-5.6E-45, 5.6E-45
-5.6E-45, -4.2E-45, -2.8E-45, -1.4E-45, 0, 1.4E-45, 2.8E-45, 4.2E-45

-0, 0
No output, though printing either 0 or -0 would be allowed (but not both)

299.9998, 300.0002
299.9998, 299.99982, 299.99985, 299.99988, 299.9999, 299.99994, 299.99997, 300, 300.00003, 300.00006, 300.0001, 300.00012, 300.00015, 300.00018, 300.0002

1.9999998, 2.000001
1.9999998, 1.9999999, 2, 2.0000002, 2.0000005, 2.0000007, 2.000001

-3.4028235E38, -3.402822E38
-3.4028235E38, -3.4028233E38, -3.402823E38, -3.402829E38, -3.4028227E38, -3.4028225E38, -3.4028222E38

3.4028229E38, 3.4028235E38
3.4028229E38, 3.402823E38, 3.4028233E38, 3.4028235E38
```

Comment: 1. The header says doubles, but the question talks about `binary32`. Which of the various sizes permitted by IEEE 754 may be used? 2. More seriously, this is just a loop round an abuse of pointers (in C) or a library function to convert a bit-pattern from int to float (in pretty much any other language which supports IEEE 754). It doesn't offer much scope for creativity.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was hoping to find some cases of duplicated numbers, but I haven't found any.  I realized that this was because the radix I'm using is `2`.  Would it be interesting if I enforced a radix of `10`?  Not every language has floating points like that (Decimal in C# is the only one I know of), so I'm not sure how relevant this challenge would be.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. Duplicated numbers?

Answer (score 0):

## Coaxial and Copolar?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[trigonometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry)

## Introduction

*SANDBOX NOTE: Diagrams soon*

*Copolar*: Two triangles `ABC` and `A'B'C'` (not necessarily in the same plane) are said to be copolar if and only if the lines `AA'`, `BB'`, and `CC'` are concurrent at one point `V`.

*Coaxial*: Supoose two triangles `ABC` and `A'B'C'` are defined such that `AB` and `A'B'` intersect at `X`, `AC` and `A'C'` intersect at `Y`, and `BC` and `B'C'` intersect at `Z`. Then, the two triangles `ABC` and `A'B'C'` are said to be Coaxial if and only if `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are collinear.

[*Desargue's Theorem*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DesarguesTheorem.html): Copolar triangles are coaxial, and conversely.

## The Challenge

Your challenge is to write **two entire programs** (but not necessarily in the same language, if you so desire) which detect whether or not two triangles are Coaxial/Copolar. One program must detect the existence of `V`, and the other must check the collinearity of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` (As defined above). You should provide some explanation or proof that your two programs perform these two different checks. Your score in this challenge is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two programs, with lowest score being dubbed winner.

## Input

You will receive `6` vectors, all of which containing an `x`, `y`, and `z` floating-point Cartesian coordinate, to represent the vertices of `ABC` and `A'B'C'`. This information may be received by your program in any convenient format, including command line arguments, nested lists, etc. **The two programs you submit should take input in the same manner**.

## Output

Your program should print a truthy value if `ABC` and `A'B'C'` are coaxial/copolar, and a falsey value otherwise. As this will likely require floating-point calculations, we establish some leniency:

Choose a constant value `0 < ERR < 0.01`, for use in both programs.

- If the pairwise intersections of `AA'`, `BB'`, and `CC'` intersect within `ERR` units of one another, the given triangles should be considered copolar.
- If the point `Z` lies closer than `ERR` distance from the line `XY`, the given triangles should be considered coaxial.

Standard techniques for checking floating point calculation equality should be sufficiently accurate for this challenge.

Since copolar triangles are also coaxial, the programs should output the same value in all but extreme cases.

It should be assumed that any cross section of the cartesian space provided is an [Extended Euclidean Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#The_extended_Euclidean_plane). Note that it is possible that the vertex `V` or any of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` may be an [ideal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity), and this is a case that should be prepared for.

## Test cases

*SANDBOX NOTE: Coming soon...*

Comment: Levenshtein distance between two programs has been tried before and is now well-known to be completely useless as a winning criterion. Anyone with half a brain can score 1, and sometimes it's even possible to vary the input enough to detect the cases and score 0.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are being served! Sibling rivalry ensues! Each of the twins wants the maximum quantity of cookie. The problem is that the cookies are of somewhat different sizes, not surprising since they are home baked. So you weigh each of the cookies and devise a program to help you allocate them to each twin such that the difference in total weight of the cookies each twin gets is minimized. Coding up the program is your task today!

### Input

Each case is described on a single line that begins with the number of cookies (no more than 100) followed by the weight of each (in integer grams, no more than 1000 grams).

### Output

For each case, display the minimum total weight difference.

### Sample Input

5 6 8 5 2 6

2 25 62

## Sample Output

1

37

---

I asked this earlier and it was put on hold. Not sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: First you need a winning criterion. Code golf (shortest valid code wins) would work well here. Another possibility would be fastest code, but that would be harder to judge - you'd probably need to run every answer on your machine, in a number of different languages. Popularity contest is hard to write a good question for, and is best saved for questions where there is no other way of judging. If you don't have a strong preference, I'd go with code golf.

Comment: An edge case to consider: Will the input ever be just 0 followed by no cookies? Whichever way you decide, it's worth mentioning this explicitly in the question so people know whether to plan for that.

Comment: You had asked for the total weight of cookies to be minimized, which I suspect was not what you intended, so I've edited it to ask instead for the *difference* in total weight to be minimized. If this wasn't what you intended feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: That clears it up a lot, thank-you, @trichoplax

Comment: You're welcome. You'll still need to do some further editing to address my first 2 comments, then after that hopefully others will comment with anything else that needs improving that I've missed.

Comment: This is a trivial variant of [this older question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8655/194) and IMO close enough to count as a dupe.

Comment: I believe the question was closed as a duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51468/help-me-carry-my-shopping-bags) because it's exactly the same, just about cookies instead of shopping bags.

Answer (score 0):

## Count the ones!<sub><sup><sub><sup>(better title needed)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) *[**Sandbox-note:** Is this really still code-golf?]*

[counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) *[**Sandbox note:** Need to find descriptive tags]*

**Void Corp needs you!**

Thanks to extreme advancements in a technology called *null-space* we are able to compress any number of 0-bits into just one memory block. The problem is that storing 1-bits is extremely expensive now. To evaluate which data we should keep we need a program that count all 1-bits in a string. Sadly our programmer is currently in forced vacation after a caffeine-incident, so it is up to you now to help us out.

Your code should contain as few 1-bits as possible when stored in *null-space*.

We have heard of this strange *Unary*. As our programmer is the only one able to understand it, we are currently not able to implement it.

## Task

Write a program that counts all 1-bits in a given string.

You may provide a function or fully functional program. Input will be provided via STDIN or argument and should be printed to STDOUT or returned.

Your answer must be in an existing language, especially the interpreter must already exist. No retro-active coding of a language that consists entirely of **NUL** (unless I missed it). *[**Sandbox note:** Don't tell me there is such a thing.]*

## Scoring

Count the 1-bits in your code. Fewest amount wins.

*[**Sandbox note:** Should add script to paste code into for evaluation]*

### Sandbox Questions

What do you think of the task? It seems pretty basic to me, the twist is the Scoring.

What do you think of the scoring? I want to encourage usage of obscure/lengthy commands which are normally not used in CodeGolf. Your opinion?

Does someone happen to have a script for evaluation lying around?
Do you have anything to add?

Is [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) appropriate for this question?

Comment: IMO this is a variant of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4434/194 and the twist isn't particularly twisty. I would vote to close as dupe.

Comment: Also the tag you would want, just fyi, is [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: Dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/source-code-ecological-footprint

Comment: @ThomasKwa Indeed...

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed Width

[Related](https://xkcd.com/276/).

```
We like fixed width. We want you to evaluate a string
on it's "fixed width"-ness. However, this string will
not be a regular string. This input will be presented
to your code as thus: "name1, name2, lin1,..., linN".

Each of linK is a single line of a transcript; you'll
assume that the speakers alternate, and that each lin
is will not have trailing whitespace, like this:
```

You may take input in the form of a function or a program, as a string with commas, a list, or a series of arguments.

Say your input is `rob, emily, hi, hey you, last night was nice, the best i've had`. Then, the result would be:

```
<rob> hi
<emily> hey you
<rob> last night was nice
<emily> the best i've had
```

Then, this input would have a "fixed width"-ness of 2. This is what you would return/print. That is, you are to output the length of the longest run of fixed width messages.

### Test cases

```
input => output

rob, emily, hi, hey you, last night was nice, the best i've had => 2
a, b, hello, hola!, no, what?, why, why not, abcdef, fededa, 012345 => 3
```

---

I think this should be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but I think this could also work as a fixed-width [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

## Natural Language Calculator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Background**

You are working at Wolfram Alpha, when a big fire occurs, wiping out much of the hardware infrastructure, losing much of the code. Now you are assigned to the natural language team working on writing new code for converting natural language to mathematical expressions to be evaluated. You must parse the following commands and even do mixed commands!

**Challenge**

The input will be a string, obviously. For multiple operations, there will be commands within input of commands.

Pi and e are simply inputted as "pi" and "e". Other special numbers are not needed to be handled.

Parse the following commands:

- Add x and y
- Subtract x and y
- Multiply x and y
- Divide x and y
- Factorial of x
- x factorial
- Exponent base n of x
- Log base n of x
- Natural log of x

You must deal with it case-insensitively. For example "5 Factorial" gives the same result ad "5 factorial" or "5 FAcTorial".

**Testcases**

```
> "Add 4 and 5"
9
> "Multiply 6 and 10"
60
> "Divide 144 and 12"
12
> Exponent base 10 of 3
1000
> 3 factorial
6
> 3
> Add 5 factorial and 2
122
> Exponent base e of natural log of e
e
> natural log of e
1
```

Comment: -1 Unclear challenge.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan "*Still in the works and need to add more detail*"

Comment: Well, I think the sandbox is not for brainwashing idea, but to polish the challenge while detecting it if the challenge is duplicate.

Comment: The sad thing is, most of these are actually things in AppleScript already. Shame that there's no eval for i- oh, wait, there's a library for that in Java.

Comment: Even if this were cleaned up, I don't see what it adds to the many existing  "process arithmetic in english" challenges.

Answer (score 0):

## Hexotria number

Inspired by [Triangular Ulam spiral](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69468/ulam-spiral-on-a-triangular-grid#69468)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

For instance we write number in triagular spiralling way

```
      30  10  26  51
    31  11  09  25  50
  32  12  01  08  24  49
33  13  02  00  07  23  48
  14  03  04  05  06  22
    16  17  18  19  20
      39  40  41  42
```

Then we read in spiralling hexagonal way (Starting from 0, 1 ,2) then we get

```
0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 3, 17, 18, 19, 6, 23, 24, 25, 26, 10, 30, 31, 32, 33, 14, 16, 39, 40, 41, 42, 20, 22, 48, 49, 50, 51
```

Your challenge is given a number (i) output the i'th item in that sequence. `i` is zero based. Shortest code wins.

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8048/8478

Comment: Otherwise, this sounds like a nice challenge :). You should specify whether `i` is 0-based or 1-based or whether people can choose.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Now, what's missing in this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## The quitting log-in

This program relies on the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> at specified times to show him the secret message (the secret message is just `m` to avoid polluting the byte count with un-avoidable chars).

Given a 3 digit enter code that may be specified anywhere (just give directions to find it inside your source code) let the user see the message if he quits at the n-th (1-indexed, zero may never be present in the pass-code) `?` each time.

The user should press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get to the next question.

If the user does not press `<Control-C>`, nine successive prompts should be shown.

Given a code `523`

```
?
?
?
?
? <Control-C>
?
? <Control-C>
?
?
? <Control-C>
m
```

Given a code `123`

```
?
?
? <Control-C>
? <Control-C>
? <Control-C>
```

Comment: Instead of `m` you could make the program output something truthy or falsy depending on whether the pattern is correct. Also do you want to specifically make this a challenge about catching process signals? Because that will rule out a lot of languages, and if it's not your intention you could also have the user enter a specific string instead of having them send Ctrl+C.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I actually want to make this a  challange about handling `KeyboardInterrupt` because I have never seen it in a code-golf challange, as far as `m` vs truthy falsy is concerned, it is just a matter of `r?'m':''` now, and the message may in theory be a long string, one char just to avoid cluttering the code up

Comment: There's at least http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63105/8478 but I feel like we've had another one, too.

Answer (score 0):

## Queuing queues

I recently found a great site, [Dubtrack](https://www.dubtrack.fm), for all my music needs.
However, it features a very interesting method of ordering, which contains a queue of users, and each user has their own personal queue.

The user queue loops through each of the users that have songs, and plays the top song from their individual queue.  This means that:

1. When there is a single user, it simply plays the songs in the order that user added them.
2. When there are multiple users, it interleaves the songs.

However, users' queues aren't always filled, and when a user adds his first song to the queue, **the user is added to the end of the user queue**.

For example, say there were 3 users each with the following queues (at time 0):

```
0 [1,10,100,1000]
0 [2,20]
0 [3,30,300]
```

then the resulting playlist would look like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 100, 300, 1000]
```

However, if a user were to add his queue during the 4th song:

```
0 [1,10,100,1000]
0 [2,20]
0 [3,30,300]
3 [4,40,400,4000]
```

Then the playlist would look like

```
                      v New user's song finally plays
[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 4, 100, 300, 400, 1000, 400, 4000]
          ^ New user added here, but user 2 and 3 are still in front
```

Your challenge is to take a list of queues and join times, and return them in single playlist.  You are guaranteed that there will be at least 1 queue at time `0`, and that additional users won't be added after all the songs have played.

## Test cases

```
Input
0 [1,5,3,7,2,6,3]
Output
[1,5,3,7,2,6,3]

Input
1 [3,6,9,12]
0 [4,10]
Output
[4,10,3,6,9,12]

Input    
0 [1,10,100,1000]
0 [2,20]
0 [3,30,300]
3 [4,40,400,4000]
Output
[1,2,3,10,20,30,4,100,300,400,1000,400,4000]

Input
11 [3000]
3 [6,8,10,11,0]
5 [4,100,14,12,0]
0 [0,1,2,3,4,5]
11 [2000]
Output
[0,1,2,3,6,4,8,4,5,10,100,11,14,3000,2000,0,12,0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the queue system works. You say "when a user adds his first song to the queue, the song is placed at the end of the interleaving process", but in the second example, song `4` is placed before song `21`, not at the end of the existing queue. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "a queue".

Comment: @Zgarb I made a few changes:  There is a queue of "users" and each user has their own individual queue.  I've also termed the output as a "playlist".  Do you understand now?

Comment: It's much better now, yes. But just to be clear, when a song is popped from a user's personal queue to be played, that user is effectively sent to the bottom of the user queue, right?

Comment: Yep, that's how it works.

Comment: What assumptions can be made about the song IDs? Are they guaranteed to be non-negative integers between e.g. 0 (inclusive) and 2^31 (exclusive)? Can answers choose between that or strings? Something else?

Comment: Both of those sound like good options.

Answer (score 0):

## There's an <s>App</s> SE Site for that

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)[stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)[file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system)

Oftentimes, when searching through StackExchange, I find myself seeking to post a question about something or another, but not knowing where to post it. That's where you come in.

### The Challenge

Write a full-functioning program that does the following:

1. Takes an input string
2. Attempts to find suitable SE sites relevant to the input string (this is *very* flexible, but should not be returning English.SE for questions about Coffee, for example)
3. Attempts to find 3 questions on each suitable site that may relate to the input string (should match the list of questions if I searched in the search bar of each site, sorted by number of votes)
4. "Output" is a folder tree written to disk with the following qualities:

   - The highest folder of the tree should be named the input string.
   - The second-highest layer should consist of folders named the same as the sites on which the input string was found suitable.
   - The third layer should be <=3 .md files that are named the same as the questions found when searching through the suitable sites, the contents of which are the question's markup content.

## Rules

- You MUST query for this information. I don't want 50EB solutions.
- "Suitable sites" are defined as the keyword appearing in the site description.
- Run time should be <5 minutes for >3 MB internet speed.

## Bonuses

There are no bonuses.

Remember - SE is a big place now, and, as of such, we must compensate with short code. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), everybody, so the shortest solution wins!

Comment: "*Whatever defines "suitable" for your code is up to you*" is too broad IMO.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Refined. Please see edit.

Comment: @RikerW I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: Me neither. lol

Comment: What's the yardstick for whether two words are synonyms? If that's up to answers to decide, no-one will waste any bytes on it, so you should simplify the question by removing the mention of synonyms. Otherwise you need to add a source (and risk the question being largely a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] for that list).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## How many swaps do I need to sort a list?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

A *swap* is defined as an operation on a list that exchanges the position of exactly two elements:

```
[9, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 7, 9, 1, 4, 4, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 7, 0, 1]
       | <----------------> |
[9, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 3, 7, 9, 3, 4, 4, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 7, 0, 1]
```

Of course, every list can be sorted via some sequence of swaps (e.g. that's how Shell sort works).

Given a list of single-digit integers, determine the minimum number of swaps you need to sort the list.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

Input may be in any convenient, flat list format, as long as the data is not preprocessed.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

#### Test Cases

(will follow)

#### Sandbox Questions

- If the list elements are distinct, this is simply: a) determine ordering, b) treat ordering as permutation and decompose into cycles, c) subtract one from each cycle's length and sum the results. (Which would make this a duplicate.) Off the top of my head, I can't think of a similarly simple algorithm when duplicates are allowed. Can anyone else?

Comment: Bubble sort only swaps adjacent pairs and that's much easier to calculate (at least for distinct elements) - all you need do is to consider each distinct pair of elements and count how many pairs are out of order.

Comment: @Neil Of course. But if you can sort a list via swaps of adjacent elements, you can also sort it via swaps of arbitrary elements.

Comment: I just didn't think it was the best, um, sort of sort to use to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: @Neil fixed? :)

Comment: Now that's what I call an excellent sort of sort to demonstrate the idea!

Comment: Oddly enough I was thinking of a challenge very much like this.

Answer (score 0):

### Employee Scheduler

This challenge is simple: make a schedule for the student workers in my department!

Student workers have to regularly update their availability to accommodate class changes every semester, and the number of student workers we have employed constantly varies. Also, student workers are not allowed to work more than 20 hours a week. Meanwhile, there are several stations that need to be manned throughout the work day.

#### Required Minimums:

Your program should at least be able to do the following:

1. Input a list of first names and times of availability
2. Output a one month schedule that covers 4 stations 5 days a week from 800 to 1700

If there is a gap of time that cannot be filled based on the availability given, you should fill that gap with an obvious name like "NEEDED" or something like that. Note that the times of availability will depend on the day of the week.

Your program does need to able to at least run in Windows. Also, your program absolutely may not schedule workers more than 20 hours in a week.

You may assume that all student workers have been trained in all stations, so anybody can work anywhere. You also may assume that the month for which you should generate a schedule is following month (so if it is January, make a schedule for February).

#### Other Notes:

You'll notice I'm not specifying an IO method you must use. I trust you as a coder to pick a method that suits your program, just keep in mind this is a popularity contest and ease of use is an inevitable factor. Also, you may use 12 or 24 hour time at your discretion. Please list both the method of IO and 12 or 24 hour time in your description.

Some things that I'm not requiring, but would definitely earn some kudos from me:

- Use a station priority system when creating the schedule (some stations should be covered before others)
- Try to maximize the hours given to each student (while not going over 20 hours per week, of course)
- Minimize overlap
- Make your output pretty (currently we use an excel spreadsheet that looks pretty nice)
- Input the number of stations
- Input the month for which to generate
- Generate multiple months (using the same availability)
- Input holidays and days the department is closed
- Make your program run on both Windows and OS X
- Golf your program

#### Examples

INPUT:

```
Jack    m:0900-1530 t:0800-1530 w:0900-1200 th:0800-1530 f:0900-1700
John    m:0000-0000 t:1300-1700 w:0900-1200 th:1300-1700 f:1000-1200
Joseph  m:0800-1000 t:1300-1700 w:0000-0000 th:1300-1700 f:0800-1000
Jannett m:1430-1700 t:0000-0000 w:1200-1700 th:1100-1400 f:1200-1700
Brianna m:0900-1430 t:0800-1300 w:0900-1430 th:0000-0000 f:1200-1700
Dianne  m:0800-0900 t:1300-1700 w:0000-0000 th:1300-1700 f:0800-1000
Megan   m:1400-1545 t:1100-1700 w:1400-1545 th:1100-1700 f:0000-0000
Sierra  m:1600-1700 t:0800-1100 w:0900-1300 th:0000-0000 f:0800-1300
Sandy   m:1345-1700 t:0800-1045 w:1345-1700 th:0800-1045 f:1200-1700
Holly   m:0800-1200 t:0800-1200 w:0000-0000 th:0800-1200 f:0800-1200
```

OUTPUT:

```
Monday              Tuesday          Wednesday        Thursday        Friday

STA 1               STA 1            STA 1            STA 1           STA 1
Joseph 8-10         Holly 8-1130     Brianna 9-1430   Jack 8-11       Joseph 8-10
Jack 10-1430        Brianna 1130-13  Jannett 1430-17  Megan 11-17     Holly 10-12
Jannett 1430-1700   Joseph 13-17                                      Desiree 12-17

STA 2               STA 2            STA 2            STA 2           STA 2
Riane 8-9           Sierra 8-11      John 9-12        Holly 8-11      Sierra 8-1
Brianna 9-1430      Megan 11-17      NEEDED 12-1430   Jannett 11-2    Brianna 13-17
Megan 1430-1545                      Megan 1430-1545  Joseph 14-17    
NEEDED 1545-16                       NEEDED 1545-17
Sierra 16-17

STA 3               STA 3            STA 3            STA 3           STA 3
Holly 8-12          Sierra 8-1045    Holly 8-12       Sierra 8-1045   Riane 8-10
NEEDED 12-1345      NEEDED 11-13     Sierra 12-1      Jack 11-1       Tyler 10-12
Sandy 1345-17       Riane 13-17      NEEDED 13-1345   Riane 13-17     Sandy 12-17
                                     Sandy 1345-17

STA 4               STA 4            STA 4            STA 4           STA 4
NEEDED 8-9          NEEDED 8-13      NEEDED 8-9       NEEDED 8-13     NEEDED 8-9
Jack 9-10           John 13-17       Jack 9-12        John 13-17      Jack 9-14
NEEDED 10-1430                       NEEDED 12-17                     NEEDED 14-17
Jack 1430-1530
NEEDED 1530-17
```

As you can see, in this case the input `0000-0000` means that person is not available on that day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

## Monophonic Pitch Detection

**Tags:** [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

#### Sandbox Notes

- Still in progress. I haven't made any of the test cases or snippets yet.
- This is intended to be an easier and more accessible alternative to [Polyphonic Pitch Detection](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8140/46855).
- Would this still be a duplicate of the polyphonic version? Solutions could "work" in both challenges, but algorithms that work for this one would perform *extremely* poorly (typically monophonic algorithms fail outright with multiple waveforms and produce a completely incorrect frequency) for the other.

---

Take an array of samples, and output the frequency of the waveform found in the samples.

---

You will receive a list of samples as signed 16-bit integers at a fixed sample-rate of 44100 samples-per-second. Each input will only contain one waveform in the range of 100hz to 2000hz.

You must output the frequency detected (in hertz) with up to 2 decimal places of precision.

#### Test Cases

Each test case is on it's own line. Each line begins with the name of the test case, followed by a semi-colon (`;`), then the frequency present in the test case (with 2 decimal places of precision), followed by another semi-colon, then the samples separated by commas:

`Test Case Name;123.45;3,75,1234,56789,4321,-23,-408,-9266,41,0,etc...`

*(link to test case file, will include synthesized waveforms, real instrument sounds, added noise, different pitches)*

#### Scoring

The score of a submission is a percentage based on how close the submission's results are to the actual frequency of each test case. Specifically it will calculated using the formula in the snippet below (use this to calculate your score):

*(snippet for calculating score)*

#### Rules

- No built-ins that detect pitch or extract waveform frequencies are allowed.
- Helper functions that are designed to aid frequency analysis like [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) are permitted.
- You may optimise your solution for the test cases, but you cannot hard-code the results for these specific test cases.

#### Play Samples

You can hear what a list of samples sounds like by pasting it into this snippet:

*(snippet for playing sample strings or sine waves using web audio)*

#### Links

- [Overview of Pitch Detection Techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm)
- [Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)
- [YIN Algorithm](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

## Letter subsets

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Consider two letters, L1 and L2. L1 is a *solid subset* of L2 if and only if all of the lines can be placed on L2 without rotating or breaking L1 or marring the image of L2; this is L1 s.s. L2, symbolically. For example, I s.s. T because you can place the line of I on T without a difference, and C s.s. O for the same reason. Here are all the letters (L1, L2) for which L1 s.s. L2 and L1 ≠ L2:

```
L1  L2
F   E
C   O
I   T
I   L
O   Q
```

Two letters L3 and L4 share the relation of *variant subset* (i.e. L3 is a variant subset of L4, or L3 v.s. L4) if and only if some rotation of L3 exists where L3 s.s. L4. Here are all the letters (L3, L4) for which L3 v.s. L4 and L3 ≠ L4:

```
L3  L4
F   E
C   O
I   T
I   L
O   Q
V   A
I   H
H   I
I   N
I   M
I   B
I   V
I   X
I   Z
I   P
I   E
I   W
I   R
I   K
I   F
I   D
N   Z
Z   N
T   H
G   Q
```

### Specs

Your input will be two letters. You may take them as a string, two characters, or two numbers representing those characters, as arguments, read from STDIN, or from a file. With these two letters, you are to output their relation. You should favor s.s. over v.s. over nothing. Your output will be `ss`, `vs`, or nothing. Your program may do anything if the input is not a pair of **uppercase** letters. Your program should pass all of the above relations when given those letters as input.

---

## ~META~

Suggestions? Any letters in v.s. or s.s. I missed? Any you don't understand?

Comment: If `I` is a single vertical line (which it is in some fonts, but not all), why is it an s.s. of `T` and `L` but only a v.s. of `B`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `H`, `K`, `M`, `N`, `P`, `R`? (And in some fonts it might also be an s.s. of `W`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I missed those, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Knights and Knaves [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73143/knights-and-knaves)

*Undeleted so that comments are visible*

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5419/code-golf-solve-a-knights-and-knaves-logic-problem-by-parsing-english).

Comment: I find some of the wording rather confusing, in particular the statement that `Is` is a logical operator (shouldn't that be `Iff`?) and the references to de Morgan's laws, which are theorems and not operators. But essentially ISTM that this question differs from the other question only in the parser (which makes some simplifications and adds a case to parse `=>`), and I would vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'll add some stuff to clear up the IS thing, because you're right, it isn't really a logical operator, I was just trying to keep it simple. I think that the parsing of conditionals and having to actually use De Morgan's makes this challenge significantly more complicated than the other. Especially given that other is literally focused on the English parsing, whereas this is focused only on the logic. Basically you cannot "trivially" change answers from the other question to solve this one.

Comment: I really can't see any fundamental difference between the two questions with respect to de Morgan's laws. The earlier question doesn't have a direct `Not` operator, so requires abusing `Nor`, but it allows arbitrary nesting of clauses.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you quote the other challenge? I'm reading it and not seeing anything to do with De Morgan's. I'm specifically looking at the "Parsing" section.

Comment: `both [clause] and [clause]` `either [clause] or [clause]` `neither [clause] nor [clause]` between them contain everything you need to set up a clause equivalent to `~(A ^ B)` or `~(A v B)`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, but you don't have to parse the negations of con/disjungtions and hence do not need to use De Morgan's at all. Sure, they end up equivalent at the end of the day but that's not the point. I'm not allowing people to read inputs and say "Hey, X is equivalent to Y... why don't I just enter Y instead." If it can't parse X, then it fails the spec.

Comment: There's nothing in your question which obliges people to use de Morgan's laws either. They just need to brute-force all possible assignments and evaluate the expressions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, and they would be in their rights to do so. However, that is not how people actually solved the other question. And it may or may not be the best way to solve this one. So sure, that is a valid concern, but not evidence that this is a duplicate.

Comment: It *is* how ugoren solved the previous one; Howard's solution is harder to understand, so I'm not sure exactly how it works.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hmm, sorry I must have missed that. That is true. There is still the matter of conditional logic however.

Answer (score 0):

## Reasoning

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Introduction

Reasoning is one of the most important human capabilities, often counted
as what separates us from other species. This capacity, however, takes up
a substantial portion of our meaty brain. Your challenge is to recreate
a reasoning system in a much abbreviated form.

### Definitions

The challenge, is, given a universe of objects and *n*-ary relations and a set
of facts and laws on the relations, to determine whether a hypothesis is a fact
or not. The language in which these are expressed are drawn from the
alphabet "012345789RC@ " under the following rules (in EBNF with an ad-hoc expansion).

1. An *unbound-variable* is denoted by a sequence of digits denoting a non-negative integer. For example, `3` is a variable which we may read as "object 3".

   natural = non-zero-digit , { digit } ;

   unbound-variable = natural ;
2. A *bound-variable* is denoted by a "@" followed by an unbound variable.

   bound-variable = "@" , unbound-variable ;
3. A *variable* is either a bound-variable or an unbound-variable

   variable = bound-variable | unbound-variable ;
4. A *relation-identifier* is denoted by a capital "R" followed by a single digit denoting its arity and then a natural number identifying it.

   relation-identifier(n : digit) = "R" , n , natural ;
5. A *relation* is denoted by a relation identifier followed by a sequence of variables whose length matches its arity.

   relation = relation-identifier(a) , a * { " " , variable } ;
6. A *consequence* is denoted by a capital "C" followed by two relations.

   consequence = "C" , relation , relation ;
7. An *expression* is either a consequence or relation of that magnitude.

   expression = consequence | relation ;

The inference rules are the following:

1. From `C R R'` and `R` (where `R` and `R'` are relations) to infer `R'`.
2. From `E` to infer `E{@m=p}` where `E{@m=p}` is the expression `E` with all instances of bound-variable `@m` replaced by variable `p`.

### The Challenge

You will be given a sequence of at least one expression, that will be provided as a newline separated strings on the stdin. The first of these will be a relation with no bound variables -- the hypothesis. The remaining expressions are the facts. Your program must indicate whether the hypothesis can be infered from the facts or not. It does this by printing any of the following strings to the stdout: "true" (case-insensitive), "+", "1", "yes". Any other input will be interpreted as claiming the hypothesis cannot be infered from the facts.

### Test cases

```
>input:
R00
>expected output:
false|no|whatever

>input:
R00
R00
>expected output:
true

>input:
R10 0
R10 @1
>expected output:
true

>input:
R20 4 9
R20 9 4
CR20 9 4R20 4 9
>expected output:
true

>input: 
R2859 7 163
R2859 @0 163
>expected output:
true

>input:
R10 5
R10 1
CR10 1R10 2
CR10 2R10 3
CR10 3R10 4
CR10 4R10 5
>expected output:
true

>input:
R10 6
R10 1
CR10 1R10 2
CR10 2R10 3
CR10 3R10 4
CR10 4R10 5
>expected output:
false   

>input
R20 4 5
R20 9 6
CR20 6 @0R20 7 @0
CR20 @0 7R20 @0 4
CR20 @0 9R20 5 @0
CR20 @0 @1CR20 @1 @0
>expected output: 
true

>input
R20 4 5
R20 9 6
CR20 6 @0R20 7 @0
CR20 @0 7R20 @0 5
CR20 @0 9R20 5 @0
CR20 @0 @1CR20 @1 @0
>expected output: 
false
```

## Grading

This is a golf competition, the fewest number of bytes wins. Other restrictions are TBD.

Answer (score 0):

## Is the plate balanced? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Task

Given a grid of 1 digit numbers and a coordinate, tell me if it is balanced.

#### How to balance check

Explanation coming. I know how it works for 1d ([Balance a set of weights on a seesaw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54311/balance-a-set-of-weights-on-a-seesaw)), but don't know how it would work for 2d.

#### Input

Input will be a grid of 1 digit numbers. Each number corresponds to the amount of weight at that location.

#### Examples

```
Input:
111
111
111
1,1

Output:
truthy
```

Comment: Will the center of mass always be at integer coordinates?

Comment: No, but this is the only example I know is correct right now. Unfortunately I haven't learned now to solve this type of problem yet, and the Wikipedia entry doesn't help for this use case.

Comment: Center of mass in 2D can be found by just calculating the coordinates separately; that is, you sum up the rows and calculate the y value, then sum up the columns and calculate the x value.

Answer (score 0):

## Sloppy Shuffle

Write a program that will shuffle the numbers from 1 to 52. Rather than from your language's random facility, the result will be determined by the input. But not in any particular way -- however you choose!

**The Rules**

- The program must accept all possible (finite) inputs. It doesn't matter if it is empty, or the result of monkeys with typewriters, or anything in between. Literally any input must be accepted without (unhandled) errors.
- For each of the 52-factorial possible ways of shuffling the numbers, there must be at least one finite input that will make your program produce this permutation.
- No matter what (finite) input is given to the program, it must produce some permutation of the numbers.
- If given the same input, the program must always produce the same permutation.
- Nothing should be produced on stderr.
- Standard restrictions apply.

**Input/Output**

[Default input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) (such as stdin or command line args) are acceptable. If using stdin, any finite input from stdin must be accepted (although it doesn't all have to be read). For other input methods, use your best judgement in accepting arbitrary binary or string data as appropriate.

[Default output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) (such as stdout) are acceptable. The form of the output should be the number from 1 to 52 in some order corresponding to the permutation as appropriate for your output method.

**Scoring**

This is code golf. The shortest answer in bytes wins!

However, in case of a tie in code length, the first tiebreaker is the maximum over all permutations of the minimum input length needed to generate that permutation. The program that has a larger minimum input wins.

(That may have been confusing, so an example: if program A can generate any permutation with no fewer than 100 bytes of input, but program B needs at least 1000 bytes to generate the identity permutation, program B wins the tie.)

**Example**

This is an example of a program which fulfills the requirements in Lua:

```
-- return a number from (1,n) depending on input
local function pick_from(n)
  local str = io.read() or ""

  -- always proceed even if input is not a number
  local num = math.floor(tonumber(str) or 0)

  -- guard in case of parsing overflow (e.g. input of 1e99999999999)
  if num ~= num or num > 1000 or num < -1000 then
    num = 0
  end

  return 1 + (num % n)
end

-- create a list of 52 numbers
local deck = {}
for i = 1, 52 do
  deck[i] = i
end

-- Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
for i = 52, 1, -1 do
  local j = pick_from(52)
  if i ~= j then
    deck[i], deck[j] = deck[j], deck[i]
  end
end

for i = 1, 52 do
  print(deck[i])
end
```

Notice that although I used the Fisher-Yates algorithm, the property that Fisher-Yates generates a permutation uniformly is irrelevant to the correctness of the program.

Another note -- if you never read at least log2(52!) bytes from the input, it is probably impossible for your program to generate all permutations.

Comment: As far as I can tell, printing the input unchanged satisfies the spec.

Comment: "Each possible finite input must produce some permutation of the numbers." If the input is not a valid output (as most are not), simply printing the input does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Okay, the intent was that every input must be accepted, but I can see how that is not clear from what I wrote. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: Okay, so I see that there must be some input that corresponds to every permutation. But input can be literally anything? I'm also confused by what you mean by "uniform" that is usually used in regard to some sort of probability distribution, but you say that the same input must always do the same permutation, so there doesn't seem to be anything random.

Comment: Yes, the intent is that the program should accept literally any input and produce a valid output. Also true that there is nothing random. I am trying to use "uniform" to evoke the sense that outputs would be evenly distributed across inputs (maybe for each bounded size). However, since I am explicitly not requiring it, it does not need to be well defined for the question to be well-formed. I thought that using the word "shuffle" people would think they are required to use a uniform shuffling algorithm. Maybe it is better to leave this part off.

Comment: Why don't you go with the defaults (function/full program, input via stdin/function argument/command line, etc)? They've proven to work for most challenges.

Comment: I don't want to restrict anyone. I thought it was safer to be more specific, but I guess maybe people don't need to be told. I was a little worried about input methods since my idea of accepting arbitrary input may not have a well-established meaning for all input methods. However, I've tried to edit the question to remove all such restrictions.

Comment: @tehtmi: the main problem with very strict rules is that whichever one you choose it will fit some languages and will be awkward in others. Let's take your requirement for nl/space/tab separated numbers as an example: in some languages it's just a "print" of an array variable. Other languages would print brackets around and commas in-between the elements, so they have to loop over the array and print each number individually. People don't like such disadvantages for their favorite language. Please consider allowing "native array format" or "any reasonable format" for the output list.

Comment: The obvious golfed approach is to say that if the input is a valid output, print the input; otherwise print the identity permutation. In no way does it meet what I would presume to be the intent of the challenge, but it does meet the spec.

Comment: ^ yeah. I would recommend narrowing the input specs. "Input can be anything" will  usually get you into trouble.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: I actually have no problems with that solution. I'm not convinced, though, that it would obviously be the best solution. Probably it would be best in some languages and not in others. Checking whether an input is a permutation seems to be of similar complexity to many shuffling algorithms, but it may be more likely that some languages would have built-ins to do it.

Comment: @Liam: I think the input spec is the only thing that makes this problem interesting (and original -- there have been other shuffling golf challenges). Maybe nobody thinks it is a good question in which case it can die in the sandbox, but at least for myself, having the input as another dimension over which to optimize seemed somewhat interesting.

Comment: Many many languages have built-in sort, and sorting and then checking that `a[i] = i+1` for all `i` is sufficient.

Comment: You could possibly around the described solution by limiting input to a set number of characters and then require that each of the 52! outputs have at least a certain number of things that map there, or require that every output has the exact same number of inputs that map there.

Comment: Okay, so you are iterating through a list once and doing some simple logic. In my (ungolfed) example, I iterate through a list once and do some simple logic. My loop can basically be reduced to three logical steps -- input, sanitize input, swap. Your loop only has one logical step -- compare. However, you have three logical steps before your loop -- input, sanitize input, sort. In golf, it generally doesn't matter if steps are in a loop or not. I'm sure we could argue about my exact breakdown of the steps, but it still seems to me that both methods are similar.

Comment: I'm not a competitive golfer in anything but Lua, but even if I make fairly generous assumptions by adding features to facilitate your method, my golfed "traditional shuffle" is shorter. And like I said before, it is okay if your solution turns out to be best. I'm only rejecting the assertion that it is obviously best. As I see it, an even better solution (although I don't know of any language where it meets the spec would be) `seed(input())print(shuffle(52))`. If someone could make this work, I think it would be great.

Comment: So get all the permutations of numbers 1-52 and use indexing?

Comment: In Pyth this is literally just [.PCzS32](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.PCzS32&input=+o87bvtrogwilrb&debug=0).

Comment: @Thomas Kwa: `.PlzS52` would win the tie break -- depending on whether you allow it as a solution. (Is Pyth's presumed inability to accept an input of length 52! an implementation limitation or language limitation? I can't tell.) I wonder if there is any other option?

Answer (score 0):

**Determine if a given loan repayment schedule is a weekly or a daily schedule?**

*Problem scope*

Its a real life problem which I recently fixed with >90% accuracy but wants to know if there can be near to 100% accurate result. Winner will be the one that can show using datasets that his solution will give minimal failures.

*Problem Description*

You are given a set of repayment schedules, some of which represents a daily repayment schedule and some represents a weekly repayment schedule. Each repayment schedule is in its own file and you need to segregate the repayment schedule files in 2 buckets, daily and weekly.

No repayment would be received on bank holidays which include weekends.

A *weekly repayment schedule* means that borrowers have agreed to make regular fixed repayments on a particular weekday every week. A *Daily repayment schedule* means that borrowers have agreed to make a fixed repayment on all working days till loan gets repaid fully.

Few Borrowers may do one of these besides doing regular repayments.

1. Choose not to return on some scheduled repayment days.
2. Choose to make only partial repayment on some scheduled/unscheduled repayment days.
3. Choose to make extra repayment to catch up on previous payment or just doing prepayment.
4. May skip making any payment for extended duration.

Off course, not everyone will do all, but in real life people sometimes are not able to make payments or sometimes do catch up or part payments. At the same time, most borrowers would stick to payment schedules for most of the time of the return duration.

A sample demonstrating above conditions from a daily repayment schedule could be as follows for a person not completely regular

> Date         Repayment amount
>
> 1-Feb-2016   500
>
> 2-Feb-2016   500
>
> 4-feb-2016   500
>
> 8-Feb-2016   400
>
> 10-Feb-2016  1000
>
> 10-Mar-2016  500
>
> 11-Mar-2016  500

A sample demonstrating above conditions from a weekly repayment schedule could be as follows for a borrower not completely regular

> Date         Repayment amount
>
> 1-Feb-2016   500
>
> 8-Feb-2016   500
>
> 17-feb-2016   500
>
> 22-Feb-2016   400
>
> 07-Mar-2016  1000
>
> 14-Mar-2016  500
>
> 11-Mar-2016  500

This real life problem is related to repayment schedule of low income borrowers where anomalies like above can be considered fair owing to their meager means. The sample above are only small part of the file, not the whole file.

I have clarified some doubts at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71334/determine-if-a-given-loan-repayment-schedule-is-a-weekly-or-a-daily-schedule . Check those if possible.

Answer (score 0):

## How clean is my snow? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sub>Idea shamelessly take from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118538/how-clean-is-my-snow#comment221029_118538</sub>

---

[image]

### The challenge

Your challenge is to tell how clean my snow is. Unclean snow is any snow that is not pure white. This would be super easy except for one hiccup, not all of the image is a picture of the snow, in the case of the image above some of the image is the sky (can't you tell? I'm such a good artist!).

### Determining where the background is

[Write-up coming, it has to do with how large the splotch is and finding the biggest  white spot, so the clouds don't count]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## `ToUpperCase`... Mathematica style

For this challenge, you must write a program or function that converts every character in a string to upper case. "Wouldn't this be too broad/a duplicate/etc.?" you ask. Nope; you have to exactly implement Mathematica 10.1's `ToUpperCase` function!

### Note

`ToUpperCase` works quite peculiarly on Unicode. For example, `ß` converts to `SS`! The full replacement list (`from:to(,to);`):

```
97:65;98:66;99:67;100:68;101:69;102:70;103:71;104:72;105:73;106:74;107:75;108:76;109:77;110:78;111:79;112:80;113:81;114:82;115:83;116:84;117:85;118:86;119:87;120:88;121:89;122:90;223:83,83;224:192;225:193;226:194;227:195;228:196;229:197;230:198;231:199;232:200;233:201;234:202;235:203;236:204;237:205;238:206;239:207;240:208;241:209;242:210;243:211;244:212;245:213;246:214;248:216;249:217;250:218;251:219;252:220;253:221;254:222;255:89;257:256;259:258;263:262;269:268;271:270;275:274;277:276;283:282;301:300;305:73;322:321;328:327;337:336;339:338;345:344;353:352;357:356;367:366;369:368;382:381;945:913;946:914;947:915;948:916;949:917;950:918;951:919;952:920;953:921;954:922;955:923;956:924;957:925;958:926;959:927;960:928;961:929;962:931;963:931;964:932;965:933;966:934;967:935;968:936;969:937;977:920;981:934;982:928;987:986;989:988;991:990;993:992;1008:922;1009:929;1013:917;8458:63350;8467:8466;8495:8496;8500:63358;63154:63344;63155:8492;63156:63346;63157:63347;63159:8497;63161:8459;63162:8464;63163:63353;63164:63354;63166:8499;63167:63357;63169:63359;63170:63360;63171:8475;63172:63362;63173:63363;63174:63364;63175:63365;63176:63366;63177:63367;63178:63368;63179:63369;63180:63370;63181:63371;63182:8493;63183:63373;63184:63374;63185:63375;63186:63376;63187:8460;63188:8465;63189:63379;63190:63380;63191:63381;63192:63382;63193:63383;63194:63384;63195:63385;63196:63386;63197:8476;63198:63388;63199:63389;63200:63390;63201:63391;63202:63392;63203:63393;63204:63394;63205:8488;63206:63396;63207:63397;63208:63398;63209:63399;63210:63400;63211:63401;63212:63402;63213:63403;63214:63404;63215:63405;63216:63406;63217:63407;63218:63408;63219:63409;63220:63410;63221:63411;63222:63412;63223:63413;63224:63414;63225:63415;63226:63416;63227:63417;63228:63418;63229:63419;63230:63420;63231:63421;63232:74;63488:63514;63489:63515;63490:63516;63491:63517;63492:63518;63493:63519;63494:63520;63495:63521;63496:63522;63497:63523;63498:63524;63499:63525;63500:63526;63501:63527;63502:63528;63503:63529;63504:63530;63505:63531;63506:63532;63507:63533;63508:63534;63509:63535;63510:63536;63511:63537;63512:63538;63513:63539;63572:63540;63573:63541;63574:63542;63575:63543;63576:63544;63577:63545;63578:63546;63579:63547;63580:63548;63581:63549;63582:63550;63583:63551;63584:63552;63585:63553;63586:63554;63587:63555;63588:63556;63589:63558;63590:63558;63591:63559;63592:63560;63593:63561;63594:63562;63595:63563;63596:63564;63604:63547;63608:63561;63609:63555;63614:63613;63616:63615;63618:63617;63620:63619;63621:63549;63622:63556;63626:63544;
```

### Rules

- You cannot use a built-in that completely solves this challenge.
- If a function is written, the input is guaranteed to be a single string or equivalent.
- All characters not specified in the replacement list are to remain unchanged.
- All codepoints will be less than U+10000.
- If and only if your language can only take bytes as input, the string will be encoded in UTF-8.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Have fun!

### Test cases TBD

## Meta Questions

- What are some good test cases for this challenge?
- Is there something that I possibly missed while writing this challenge?

Comment: '"Wouldn't this be too broad?" you ask.' No I would ask "Isn't this a duplicate?" ;)

Comment: "You can't use Mathematica for this challenge." Why not just ban the built-in?

Comment: Further notes: 1. the list of transformations is short enough to be included in the post to ensure that it's self-contained. 2. You could just call it "Unicode-aware case conversion" or something. I'm pretty sure that the built-ins of languages like C# and Java will also perform the conversion the same way.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Looking at the list that's actually the only special one.

Comment: `>>> "ß".upper()
'SS'`  - Python might not do the whole list the same way, but it does do some. So reiterating Martin's comment, I wouldn't be surprised if there was something out there which did most of the list the same, if not all...

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm planning on possibly making a series out of this.

Comment: How close to solving the challenge does a builtin have to be to be disallowed? e.g. what if a builtin only gets half of them correct, and needs to encode the rest? 75% correct? 90% correct?

Comment: The list needs a bit of cleaning up. In particular, `223:83,83` is clearly erroneous.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Why? Isn't `223` the character code of `ß` and `83` the character code of `S`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, oh, I see. So what needs fixing is to document the list and describe its format.

Comment: 1. I'm fairly certain Mathematica can in fact encode *any Unicode character*, most likely by using surrogate pairs (two characters from U+D800 to U+DFFF). 2. Uppercasing `ß` as `SS` is fairly standard, but *why on Earth* would Mathematica uppercase `ÿ` as `Y` when there's a perfectly good `Ÿ` available?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I didn't want to break peoples' browsers with non-rendering characters (Mathematica uses its own custom font).

Comment: @Dennis 1. Its default encoding is UTF-8, trying to paste emoji makes the interpreter explode, `FromCharacterCode` only accepts up to U+FFFF, and trying to use surrogates renders a two invisible characters, which makes me believe this is the case. 2. One does not question the inner workings of Mathematica.

Comment: OK, my mistake. A bit of googling revealed that Mathematica's Unicode support is incomplete and exceptionally buggy.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Simpson's Rule

[Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Quadratic_interpolation) is a fairly simple method for approximating a definite integral of one variable. The idea is to approximate the function to be integrated by a series of interpolated parabolas, and then find the area under those.

As I learned in first-year calculus, the form of Simpson's Rule we'll be using is:

[image: Simpson's rule from Wikipedia]

where the width of each interval is ***h***.

Equivalently, this is the dot product with the vector `h/3([1,4,2,4,...,1])` the same length as the input.

#### Input

- An array of ***n***>1 real numbers representing the values of ***f*** at x-values equally spaced by ***h***. ***n*** will be odd.
- ***h***, a positive real number.

#### Output

The area approximation that Simpson's Rule gives.

#### Test cases

```
[0,0,0], 1 -> 0
[3,1,4,1,5], 1 -> 8

[add more]
```

Comment: Simpson's rule requires an even number of *intervals*, so there has to be an odd number of endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm a Puzzle!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task is to print the string "I'm on *OS*!", where *OS* is the operating system that the program is run on without version numbers.

Standard loopholes apply.

In addition, programs with hardcoded values (e.g. `print "I'm on AFakeOS"`) will be disqualified.

As this is Code Golf, your score will be the length of your full program.

---

Any suggestions?

Java example:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("I am a " + System.getProperty("os.name").replaceAll(" .*","")
                                     + "!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When making something in Java, "noncompetitive" is implicit.

Comment: :P I've been lurking and waiting for an idea long enough to know.

Comment: "If run in a browser (JavaScript and/or any other browser scripting languages), the browser should be output instead." Why is that? I'm pretty sure you can detect the operating system even if you're in a browser.

Comment: And my suggestion for "other bonuses, penalties, ..." is [drop all of them](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/8478).

Comment: Added Java example solution. Removed bonuses. Read the linked question.

Comment: Exactly what is acceptable output? If Windows 10, is `Windows`? `Windows 10`? `Windows NT Version 10.[build n]`?

Comment: How portable does this need to be? E.g. would `uname -o` be acceptable?

Comment: Considering that `uname` prints `Darwin` on my MacBook, and `-o` is an illegal option, `uname -o` would not work. I guess a possible definition of portable would be "works correctly on OS X, Windows, and most of the more common Linux distros"

Comment: @alphadelta That entails unambiguously defining the operative words `most of the` and `more common` in the phrase `most of the more common Linux distros`, which is objectively impossible.

Comment: Perl 5, fourteen bytes as a subroutine: `{"I'm on $^O!"}` (where `^O` is actually the F byte). (Fifteen as a program that prints: `say"I'm on $^O!"`.) I can only imagine that the golfing languages will get down to one or two bytes, then. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

## Implement the Block Sort sorting algorithm

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Block sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) is an interesting sorting algorithm (comparatively speaking).  Here are some of its important properties:

- O(n log n) time complexity in worst and average case
- O(n) time complexity in best case
- O(1) space complexity (not including the space that holds the list itself)
- Stable

If you check out this [table comparing sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), you'll see that it's the only one that has the whole row highlighted in green.

Your challenge is to write an implementation of the block sort algorithm in the fewest bytes.

Comment: I take it you're actually going to explain block sort in the spec before posting this?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'd assume so, but I don't know if I'll ever get around to it, mainly because it seems pretty tedious/complicated.

Answer (score 0):

## Advent of Code, puzzle 1

I don't know if anyone here spent their December working on the problems found on [Advent of Code](http://www.adventofcode.com), but I thought some of the simpler problems might make good code golf puzzles.

So, here's the first [one](http://adventofcode.com/day/1). There will be two challenges, and the solution should be a pair of programs, each of which solves one challenge.

Score is based on the combined byte count of the two programs.

(An alternative would be to also allow a single program that produces a tuple of the two solitions- what do you think?)

Input: An unbalanced string of open and close brackets.

Output 1: The count of the number of open brackets take away the number of close brackets.

Output 2: The index of the first close bracket that causes the running sum to reach -1.

Comment: This could be a copyright problem.

Comment: I'll contact the creator and ask his permission to reproduce his problems. I would not imagine it to be an issue but you're right that I should verify first.

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of asking for multiple programs in the same challenge and combining their byte count, if the two solutions don't influence each other at all. I'd say either ask for a single solution that computes both numbers at once, or choose one of the problems. (Also, FYI the first challenge is trivial in GolfScript and CJam, because `(` and `)` are the operators for decrement and increment.)

Comment: Yeah I actually used these as practice problems when my partner and I were learning CJam over the weekend, but I can't see anything better than a 5-byte solution in CJam for the first one: `0q~W*`. Perhaps just putting the second challenge is better for this one.

Comment: IIRC one or two of these were posted in December and deleted for copyright reasons.

Comment: The creator has now given the go-ahead for these problems to be replicated https://twitter.com/ericwastl/status/699455417768923137

Comment: Might be worth including that in the challenge to avoid repeating the same discussion when it goes to main.

Answer (score 0):

### Diopter lenses

In photography, there are thin lenses that you put in front of a photographic lens to make it behave like a close-up lens. Each of these lenses has an associated diopter value which is a positive integer. If you stack two (or more) of these lenses you get an equivalent of a lens with the diopter value that is the sum of the values of those lenses.

### The problem

Your program should take one diopter value `n` as an input. The input need not be validated.

You should output in any human readable form a list of diopter lenses such that:

- the maximum diopter value you can form by stacking the lenses is `n`,
- every diopter from `1` to `n` can be formed by stacking a combination of those lenses,
- there exists no set of fewer lenses that complies to the above rules.

### An example

Given the input of:

`6`

Print the output of

```
1
2
3
```

Because:

```
1=1
2=2
3=3
1+3=4
2+3=5
1+2+3=6
```

### The rules

This is code golf, so the objective is to write the shortest possible code, **but**, since there is a trivial solution that might not be obvious to some, I suggest that the answer be encoded by some means so one wouldn't see the solution before attempting to solve the problem.

Any type of output is accepted, as long as the program outputs correct clearly separated positive integers and no other alphanumeric character.

### My solution

python 2, 52 bytes, base64 encoded

```
bj1pbnB1dCgpCno9MQp3aGlsZSAyKnotMTxuOnByaW50IHo7eio9MgpwcmludCBuLXorMQ==
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization), [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

Comment: I think this is too much of a math problem and not enough of a code-golf problem.

Comment: That's exactly why I posted it here. Not having seen many on this site before, I was curious whether such problems were adequate for code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Hourglass simulator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a full program or function to simulate an hourglass.

#### Input

***n***, the number of seconds on the hourglass.

#### Behavior

At the start, there are ***n*** seconds on a timer, and the timer is counting down. When the user presses the spacebar with ***t*** seconds left, set the time left to ***n-t***. Terminate the program when time runs out.

This models an hourglass where the top of the hourglass is initially filled with ***n*** seconds of sand. When the spacebar is pressed, the hourglass flips by 180°. When either side of the hourglass runs out of sand, the program terminates.

[Is there anything I'm missing? This spec seems really short.]

Comment: I don't understand this spec. Are you displaying an hourglass? Does the program output anything?

Comment: "when the spacebar is pressed" seems quite limiting, especially for terminal interaction which might not flush STDIN before the end of the line. I'd allow any sort of user action, but if you want to make it specific, then sending a line/hitting enter would probably allow a lot more languages to participate.

Comment: You need to state exactly how the hourglass should be displayed

Comment: @somebody As far as I understand the challenge the program shouldn't display anything. It should just *act* like an hourglass.

Comment: @xnor cc the above

Comment: Thomas, seems likely this is going to come up again on main if you leave the spec as it is. Maybe don't talk about the "top of the hourglass" and "seconds of sand" and flipping "by 180°" but phrase the challenge in terms of a timer instead, whose current value gets subtracted from `n` each time there's user input.

Comment: @Martin I agree.

Comment: @lirtosiast shouldn't it replace `time` with `n-time`when flipped instead?

Comment: @somebody Oh, I guess that's the same behavior.

Comment: Since taking real-time input is limiting for some languages, what if you took in a list of times at which the presses happen?

Answer (score 0):

## Plotting Dynamical Systems in ASCII

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Input**:

- A Function to and from the real plane (henceforth R2) , call it `F`
- A point in R2 that is to be the center of a disk, call it `c`
- A radius, call it `r`
- An integer representing the number of iterations to be performed, call it `n`.

**Output**:

You are to output `n+1` ascii "images". The first depicts the disk `D` (with center `c` and radius `r`) and the *i*th image depicts `F^i(D)`, aka `F(...F( F(D) )...)` where we have applied `F` to `D`, and then applied `F` to `F(D)` and so on until we have applied `F` *i* times.

**Input Details**:

- `F` will always be polynomial. See below for acceptable examples.
- Any `c = (c1,c2)` given will satisfy `|c1|<50` and `|c2|<25`.
- Also, `r` will always be small enough that `D` the disk around `c` with radius `r` will contain no points with an `x` coordinate greater than 55 or less than -55 and no `y` coordinate greater than 32 or less than -32.
- `n` will be positive and less than 5.

**Output Details**

- We will be looking at a rectangular subset of R2 given by `{ (x,y) : -60 <= x <= -60 and -33 <= y <= 33}`. i.e. a rectangle with side lengths 120 and 66 centered at the origin.
- Each output image will contain 320*320 characters. This represents the above region in R2 with gradations of 0.5 along each axis.
- Each character will represent a single point in R2. For example if we just look at part of the first quadrant (with the axes labeled which you need not do)

```
      y
      ^
      |
      .............................
    7 .............................
      .............................
    6 .............................
      .............................
    5 .............................
      .............................
    4 ............................
      .............................
    3 .............................
      .............................
    2 .....................b.......     b =(10.5,2)
      .............................
    1 ..a..........................     a = (1,1)
      .............................     z = (0,0)
    0 z............................  --------> x 
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | | | | |  
                        10| 12| 14
                          11  13
```

- Points that are empty (i.e. not in `F^n(D)`) will be represented by the `.` character, whereas filled spaces will be represented by `#`.
- Each image will have the same or fewer `#` represented points in it because we will not be displaying points that are outside the region.

  **How do these maps work?**

These are iterative maps we will be dealing with. For each point `#` in a given image, to get the next image, you will apply the given map `F` to it. If the point leaves the viewing area, you need not render it. However if in a later iteration it should reenter the viewing area, it should reappear.

For the purposes of this challenge, the image of a point should be rounded to the nearest 0.5.

A map might be `F(x,y) = (4x(1-x), x+y)`

Answer (score 0):

## Implement an SR NOR latch with Life-like rules

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

In Conway's Game of Life, there exist [meta-pixels](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/OTCA_metapixel) that can have any Life-like rule. Consequently, it is possible to simulate Conway's Game of Life with itself. It is also possible to build circuit-like structures, such as wires and logic gates by mixing together different Life-like rules in the right ways.

For example, one can simulate wires with three Life-like rules: B/S, B1/S, and B2/S (where the original Game of Life has the rule B3/S23). In the gif below, which shows one way to cross parallel wires, these rules are black, blue/cyan, and green/yellow, respectively.

[image]

Building such circuit components is a fun challenge, and I encourage you to try a couple logic gates, like AND or OR.

### The Task

Your task is to construct an SR NOR latch, the most fundamental latch in circuitry. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_NOR_latch):

[image]

- If there is no signal on either R or S, leave the outputs unchanged.
- If there is a signal on R (reset), the Q output turns off and the Qbar output turns on.
- If there is a signal on S (set), the Qbar output turns off and the Q output turns on.
- You may safely assume you will never get a signal on both R and S at the same time.

Now, I used the word *signal* repeatedly because there are different ways to do wires. You can use the B1/S + B2/S combination shown above (blue and green, respectively), or you can use a B1/S12 rule like this:

[image]

These methods and others have their advantages and disadvantages. This is part of the challenge.

### The Rules

- If periodic input/output is chosen, then the output should have the same period as the input. As one of the output wires will always be "on", the output from this should be periodic and infinite (like a glider gun, say).
- You may assume that periodic signals are given with a period greater than the time it takes for the latch to flip.
- Steady input must be succeeded by steady output.
- You may not make the field toroidal in any way, except for demonstration, like the wire crossing example above. This is intended to disallow cheating by wrapping vertically so no wire crossing is needed.
- If the circuitry is periodic, you may assume the input signal arrives at the most convenient time.
- Initially, the Q output should be off and the Qbar output should be on.

### Scoring

***Precise details on how to weight these is to be determined.***

- Fewer rules is better. The wire crossing example above has three rules: B/S for black, B1/S for blue, and B2/S for green.
- Smaller is better. Area will be considered, as in the minimum bounding box needed to contain all necessary pixels that are not part of a wire. For instance, the wire crossing example above has a bounding box that is 4 pixels wide (the tips of the wires - where there is a blue cell without a green sheath - are not included) and 9 pixels high, for a total area of 36 pixels.
- Faster is better. For this, count the number of generations from when the input arrives to when a fully formed output leaves. For the example above, this would be 9 units of time. Here is a gif of those 9 generations, including the one before.
  [image]
- Lower latency is better. I define this to be the number of generations after a fully formed output leaves until the system has either stopped evolving or settled into a periodic pattern. The example above would have a latency of 2 generations. For periodic patterns, "settled" is defined to be when the system reaches the first pattern *that will be repeated* (the start of the cycle).

#### Note: I strongly recommend using [Variations of Life](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/varlife/) for this.

### Meta

- Additional clarifications needed?

Comment: The SN NOR latch in circuitry has continuous output on one of its signals. How is that to be modelled with the given rules? E.g. your wire crossing just sends a single instantaneous signal to the output. And what is the initial state of the latch?

Comment: Also please don't make it a popcon. :/

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Edited.

Comment: I would say [tag:code-challenge] for this. GOL *is* programming, by virtue of GOL being TC.

Comment: I think that this would be a lot easier to understand with some reordering. I read the intro, up to "*this is one way to cross wires:*", looked at the image, and had no idea what I was seeing. I just knew that it had too many colours to be GoL, which was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Substitution Cipher Programming

A simple substitution cipher maps each unique character to another character.  If my substitution cipher is `[H->6, e->U, l->V, o->)]`, then `Hello` becomes `6UVV)`.

**You must write a program `A` which inputs a string of text, and outputs the text after passing it through a substitution cipher.**

You must also be able to handle your program, `A`, as input, printing out `B`.  If possible, `B` then applies a *different* cipher, and prints out `C`, and so on, until you cannot repeat the process anymore, or until a duplicate program as been generated.

Your ciphers must:

1. Contain at least 2 substitutions, and every character in your program.
2. Change every character (i.e., no `A->A`)
3. Be unique on every substitution (i.e., if program `A` uses `x->y`, then program `B` must convert `x` into something other than `y`)
4. All be written in the same language (same version)

Your score is **ByteCount(A)/NumIterations**. You can assume that your input only consists of substitute-able characters.

For example, if `A` was `Programming`, and it generated `p80G8AMM1NG`, which generated `u79)7%vvQ-)`, which finally generated `Programming`, then there were 3 ciphers applied, and a byte count of 11, so my score would be 11/3, or approximately 3.666667.  If the final output was an invalid program, my score would still be the same.

Comment: Technically, this is the simple substitution cipher.

Comment: That's literally my title. Regardless, after the cipher, the goal is to produce another program that also does a cipher

Comment: "*If possible*" seems to imply that `B` doesn't need to be a valid program, so I *think* this spec allows any program `A` which outputs a string of the same length as itself with a consistent mapping between the characters - i.e. it doesn't need to apply that mapping to its input. On my pedantic reading of the spec, `X` would be a valid CJam answer, scoring 1/1. In fact, on a pedantic reading of the spec the empty string would be a valid answer in various languages, looping immediately but scoring 0/1 and hence unbeatable.

Comment: True, I should enforce a language length of 1.  I'm ok with `X` being a valid submission, as I think there may be another CJam submission that can get a lower score.  On the other hand, I'd be for requiring a minimum of 2 distinct characters, if that would make it more interesting

Answer (score 0):

## Dice sums from side values

I rolled some dice and put them on the table with their sides touching and forming one object with 8 horizontal sides. This means I put the dice in one of these formations (up to rotations):

```
xx   x
xx   xx  xxx
```

I read the number pips on the 8 horizontal sides in counter clockwise direction. You should write a program or function that given the list of the 8 horizontal sides in counter clockwise order returns a list of possible sums of the top pips from the dice rolling.

The layout of a die is always the following:

```
    +---+
    | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
    | 6 |
    +---+
```

For example if the input is `3 2 1 1 2 6 6 5` there are four possible configurations with top views:

```
623, 633, 643, 653 giving the output list 11, 12, 13, 14
```

with the sides always being

```
 566
3XXX2
 211
```

For the input `1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2` there is only one configuration with the top view:

```
46
31 giving the one element output list 14
```

### Input

### Output

### Examples

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Related code golf with a single die: [Determine dice value from side view](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44345/determine-dice-value-from-side-view)

Comment: Is there any input where multiple layouts are valid? (If so you'll need test cases for that.) Also your premise is a bit weird since the number of dice isn't constant. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I think there will be inputs with multiple valid layouts but I don't have code yet to check it. I will change the premise to "the 8 side numbers are all I remember". That might be a bit sensible.

Answer (score 0):

## Repeatedly convert from minimal base to base 36

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)[repeated-transformation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-transformation)

Your task is to convert an input of a list of strings which represent arbitrarily large numbers from the lowest possible base to base 36, repeatedly, until there is no further change to be made.

### Rules:

- You may not use base conversion builtins.
- From 0 to 35 in base 36 is defined as:

  ```
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
  ```
- All submissions will be tested [on this cloud 9 workspace](https://ide.c9.io/vtcakavsmoace/base-repetition) and should be uploaded for testing (along with any updates) [on this GitHub repository](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/base-repetition).
- All submissions must be written for compilers/interpreters that:

  - Are free to use.
  - Do not take up excessive space.
  - Can run with simple installations on Ubuntu 14.04.

## Test Cases:

```
Coming soon
```

Comment: Do you expect to get runtimes large enough to be measurable?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes - I expect to convert lists of large (arbitrarily precise) numbers.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. A random 1000-digit base-35 input will become a roughly 990-digit base-36 string after the first step, and the probability of going to a second step is about (1/36)^990, which is pretty negligible. But one base conversion of a number on the order of 1000 digits isn't going to take long enough to time. I would hazard a guess that you need input on the order of hundreds of millions of digits to be timeable, and then the business with the loop is completely pointless because for practical purposes it will always run once.

Answer (score 0):

## Length of a month starting from a specific day

Given a date, you are to output the number of days from today, to the last date that has a number less than today next month.

It can be calculated this way:

- If the current date in the month is not more than the number of days next month, output the number of days in the current month.
- Otherwise, output the number of days in the next month + number of days starting from the current day in the current month.

This is code-golf. Shortest code wins.

### Examples

```
2016-01-21  ->  31
2016-01-30  ->  31
2016-01-31  ->  30
2016-02-29  ->  29
```

---

Should leap years be supported?

Answer (score 0):

## Binary Arithmetic Using Unary Operators [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

This is based off a game I was playing with a friend a few years back. How many different mathematical operators can you implement using only unary operators in your source*. We were able to implement most basic arithmetic in C, but for this challenge you can use any language.

* Except under certain conditions, see below.

### Specifics:

All binary operators are disallowed, except under the following conditions:

- Binary comparison operators are allowed as long as one operand is a constant (e.g. you can do `if (x == 0)` or `if (x)` but not `if (x == y)`)
- You may use binary assignment to load user input, *only at the start of your code*, or if you create a binary `=` method using these rules.
- You may assume that all variables are default-initialized to 0; if your language does not default-initialize variables, you are allowed to set them to zero *only at the start of your code*.

Additionally, please note the following:

- You do not have to write a complete program if your language supports functions/methods.
- You can use other operators from your source (e.g. your implementation of `*` could use your implementation of `+`)
- Standard library functions follow these rules too (e.g. you can use `sqrt(x)` but not `mod(x, y)`)

### Scoring:

Your score is determined by the formula `[code size in bytes] / [number of operators implemented]`. So for example, a 300-byte program that includes the functions `+`, `-`, and `*` would count as `300/3 = 100`. Lowest score wins.

Comment: What about n-ary operators? Ternary operators? Currying? I think this has a lot of holes with languages that aren't procedural by nature.

Comment: `for (0 .. 10) { ` *stuff with* [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) `}` is a binary operator, since it takes two arguments, `0` and `10`. However, `$i=0; while(++$i <= 10) { ` *stuff with* `$i }` is unary, since the binariness of it is an initial zeroing and a comparison with a constant. Did I understand that right?

Answer (score 0):

## [title TBD]

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Input

An integer *n* between 1 and [currently 1652; TBD at the time of posting the comic], inclusive.

### Output

The XKCD title for comic number *n*. (This is the text written above the comic panel, i.e. the text content of the `<div id="ctitle">` element, not the `title`-attribute value of the `img` element. [Here's a handy list](//www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/List_of_all_comics_%28full%29), though the actual comic on [`xkcd.com`](//xkcd.com/) will govern if it differs from what's on that list. However, the title is displayed in caps and smallcaps due to CSS, and you must output it in caps and lowercase (respectively).)

(If by the time the question is posted there's a comics with an ampersand-escaped character reference — I don't think there are any now — then I'll also add a caveat about how the output of your program should include the actual character, not the ampersand-escaped reference.)

### Obviously…

I/O can be by any standard means and in any standard format. And no using the Internet to look up the title.

Comment: This might get very few (if any) answer since that is such a massive task. Maybe more appropriate as a [tag:test-battery] where submissions are scored by how many they get right divided by code size?

Comment: @MyHamDJ, oh, good idea, thanks. I'll probably edit it to that (not just now).

Comment: @MyHamDJ I disagree that the current question is too hard. It's just an exercise in compression.

Answer (score 0):

The overall task will involve extracting market data for various trading instruments (represented by unique symbols), applying some transformations and statistical functions, and displaying the results in a report.

Obtain the following QUOTES series from Bashoop: `TYQUOTES`, `FVQUOTES`

The quotes data is stored as a BBO. BBO stands for best bid/offer, which represents the best bid and ask (ask and offer are interchangable terms) in the market for a given instrument at any given time. At each timestamp it contains, in the following order: `bid price`, `bid quantity`, `ask price`, `ask quantity`

1. Calculate a `VwMpt` at each timestamp t for each instrument's QUOTES series
       `VwMpt_t = bid_price_t + (ask_price_t-bid_price_t) * (bid_qty_t / (bid_qty_t+ask_qty_t))`
2. Calculate a rolling correlation rho of `VwMpt` returns (first difference, i.e. derivative) sampled at 1 minute intervals with a lookback of 100 samples
3. On a webpage, display a plot of `VwMpt` substracted from the first sample (so the time series starts at 0) of both series on the same line chart, and below it plot the rho lined up along the same time axis. You may use a library like Flot or something similar.

To download a series with a series_id of FVQUOTES from a Bashoop instance located at 149.202.47.189:8080 you can: `curl -s -d "series_id=FVQUOTES" -d "start_ts=0" -d "end_ts=1451606400000000" -d "compress=0" http://149.202.47.189:8080/series -X GET` where `start_ts` and `end_ts` are micros send epoch. In this case we want the full history.

Comment: This still suffers from all the same issues as [your post on the main site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75167). You haven't specified a winning criterion here, but just saying *fastest code wins* isn't one, unless you specify *how* your are going to measure which code is the fastest.

Comment: What would you suggest would be a direct method to measure performance in this case? @Dennis

Answer (score 0):

## Parse default arguments

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Many languages have the concept of default/variable arguments. It basically means you can have a function that when given too few arguments, will fill in the missing arguments with specified values. For example, you can do the following in Python:

**WARNING: THE BELOW EXAMPLE CODE IS *NOT* GOLFED. PROCEED AT YOUR OWN PERIL**

```
def f(x="default string"):
  print x
```

This means that calling `f("foo")` will print "foo", but calling `f()` will print "default string".

Python also has a mechanism for handling too many arguments ("rest"):

```
def f(*stuff):
  for thing in stuff:
    print thing
```

You can of course also mix these:

```
def f(x, y="default string", *z):
  ...
```

Unfortunately, python (pre-3.5), being python, yells at you when you put a default argument before a non-default argument. That's silly. You guys are smart; you should be able to make that work.

### Challenge

Write a program, function, or whatever that when given a string representing the arguments and values passed to them, will print each argument's resulting value.

- If there are too few arguments, the mandatory arguments should be applied first, then the rest of the values into the default arguments (left-to-right).
- If there are too many, apply all values to arguments, and the remaining into the "rest" argument.

I'm even confusing myself, just look at the test cases

#### Input

- a string, array, or other reasonable format representing the parameter declaration
- a string, array, or other reasonable format representing the values passed to the arguments

#### Output

- the resulting values of all the arguments, in a reasonable format.

  *note: "reasonable format" will be defined later*

### Test Cases

Test cases will be in the following format:

```
{arg string}
{value string}
=> {output}
```

So, here they are

```
x, y, z
10, 2, 4
=> x:10, y:2, z:4

x=2, y
5
=> x:2, y:5

a, b="a", c, *d
3, 4
=> a:3, b:"a", c:4, d:[]

foo, bar=2, *baz
9, 3, "kqly", 5
=> foo:9, bar:3, baz:["kqly",5]

*x, y
"ha", 2, 3
=> x:["ha",2], y:3
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, python, being python, yells at you when you put a default argument before a non-default argument. That's silly. You guys are smart; you should be able to make that work." Actually, this is false starting Python 3.5, at least with the `f(x,y="abc",*z)` example.

Comment: @Sp3000 that's good to know! See my edit. Hopefully this still requires *some* additional processing or I may need to modify the question so Python(/ruby?) users can't just use `eval`

Answer (score 0):

## Reverse Engineering

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [reverse-engineering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-engineering) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Cops

You must write a program or function in as few bytes that takes in an integer or a set of integers, performs a defined task on them (for example, finds the prime factorisation), and gives an integer or a set of integers as output. The number of integers in input and output will be pre-defined, so will be the task. You should provide appropriate limits for the variable sizes to be supported (1 bit, 1 byte, 2 byte etc.) and any additional conditions (0 not supported, N<100, M>N, etc.), and your program should work (atleast in theory, does not need to be time or memory efficient) for all possible inputs allowed by you.

You must also submit a reference code (ungolfed) in any language that performs the exact same process in reverse. Meaning, when given the output of the first program, it should be able to deduce the input given. This should be possible (atleast in theory) for all inputs accepted by you in the first program.

For example, suppose the first program takes in two 1-byte prime numbers `m` and `n`, and outputs all prime numbers between the two of them. Since the number of integers in input must be pre-defined (and not dependent on input), we state an additional rule that there will be a total of 60 integers in output, and if there aren't that many prime numbers, then zeros will be outputed.

Input to program 1: `23 41`

Output from program 1: `29 31 37 39 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Now the second program will perform the same process in reverse.

Input to program 2: `29 31 37 39 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Output from program 2: `23 41`

### Scoring

Robbers will attempt to golf the second program as much as possible. Your score is given by the ratio of bytes in the best golfed code by a robber and the bytes in your code. So if your code is 23 bytes, and a robber writes the code for the reverse process (in any language) in 102 bytes, then your score is 102/23. Your answer is deemed ineligible for scoring if it has negative score. Highest score wins.

## Robbers

You must pick the second program submitted by a cop and attempt to golf it (in any language) as much as possible. You may submit a program or a function. You may use a different algorithm if you choose to, but the results must be exactly the same.

### Scoring

????

---

1. Is it ok to combine code-golf with cops-and-robbers like I have done?
2. What should the scoring criterion be for the robbers?
3. Is my challenge too generic (because it accepts way too many kinds of tasks)? If yes, what can I do about it?
4. Any further questions or suggestions are welcome. If you are sure of a suggestion being mandatory, you may make the edit yourself.
5. Are the tags ok?

Comment: I think your concern in 3 is very significant, I think this is way too broad. Some CNR challenges have had success by limiting the size of the output. I also think there is a significant problem with "standard language". Does APL count? I think it would be hard to argue against it being well known, and then you get stuff like Brainfuck... I think it's better to allow any language with a freely available interpreter. The upvote requirement is also rather bizarre; I don't think it should be there.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman 1. What limit should I provide? 2. Agreed, I'll make the change. 3. Up-vote requirement is only so that, in case there are low quality answers (basically extremely easy challenges) that no one pays attention to, doesn't mean they deserve to win.

Comment: I agree with lirtosiast. I'm not sure about what limit to use but perhaps take a bit of freedom away and just require the function work for bytes and always output 10 numbers, or something? This is just meant to be an idea that I think goes in the right direction, I don't think I'm at all qualified to know how to make a CNR :P In addition the tag combination has been done before, but I would add some of number/math/arithmatic depending on where you go with it.

Comment: @lirtosiast Done.

Comment: @Fry Not a bad idea, but I think I'll wait till someone else (hopefully a mod) gives their input.

Answer (score 0):

## Is this number random?: Round 2

The same as [Is this number random?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74835/is-this-number-random), but with 256 or 512 numbers in each category instead of 64; thereby making a modulo-chain infeasible to find. I hope this will encourage more interesting strategies.

---

Is this enough of a difference from the existing question to merit a new one? Are there any other flaws with the distribution? Could I change this to require splitting into 4 or so buckets instead of 2?

Comment: I think you might need to do something like 4 buckets to stop it being a dupe. I don't think increased difficulty on its own is enough to make something not a dupe (I feel like I could then just post one with 1024 numbers each etc) (but idk I wouldn't trust me, wait for more feedback).

Comment: Also: Is this number random? 2: Electric Boogaloo ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Are bug hunts like this allowed?*

## Bug Hunt - Make a change in a Git repo that Git cannot detect

**Challenge:** In the working directory of a Git repo, make a change that Git cannot detect.

- Changes can be on any file in the working directory or subdirectories that is tracked by Git.
- You may use any tool to make the change, or script your own program to do so.
- For tools, state the tool used and the steps to reproduce.
- For script or program, produce the code (please use [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) if it's too long). State the language and compiler version, if any.
- You can also do the change manually. In this case, outline the steps.
- State the version and platform of the Git binary used.
- Show a comparison between an actual clean working directory and the modified one to show the change Git can't detect.
- Show that `git status` says *"nothing to commit, working directory clean"*.

**Winning Criterion:**

- The extend of the undetected change - the bigger the change, the better.
- Reasonably latest Git version.
- Easy to reproduce.
- [Optional] Short code or simple steps. It's OK if it's not, as long as you do something exceptional.
- Most upvotes (for tiebreaker reasons).
- [Optional] You located an actual unfixed bug in the Git source code, and not just a quirk in something else.

**Restrictions:**

- Obviously, using `.gitignore` is not allowed. It's a bug hunt. Changes that Git is *designed* to ignore are not allowed. We should reasonably expect Git to see and report the change, but find that Git doesn't.
- Use latest Git version you can get. Some old version with some bug that's already fixed doesn't count.

*Please let me know if this is OK, so I can go ahead to post it on the main site.*

I could only find [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system). A suggested tag [bug-hunt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-hunt) would have been the best.

Comment: Currently bug hunts aren't allowed. Because no one proposed them, you can propose bug hunts by asking a question on meta.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this won't be allowed.  We don't allow code that exploits bugs or harms computers.

Comment: @NathanMerrill source?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4829/20198

Comment: Is this essentially asking for an AES collision?

Comment: @PeterTaylor now that wouldn't be a bug, would it? But yes, I guess that's also a valid scenario. Can you create one?

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score 0):

## Factorize Gaussian Integer

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)[complex-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)

Given a nonzero gaussian integer your program/function should return the factorization of that integer `g` into prime factors `pi` and an unit `u`:

```
g = u * p1^e1 * ... * pk^ek
```

As the factorization is only unique up to units, we make following restrictions

- All primes should `p` should be in the first quadrant, that means that `Re(p) > 0` and `Im(p) ≥ 0`.
- The unit should be represented as power of `i`. It should have the lowest nonnegative exponent.
- The primefactors should be sorted by the real part increasingly. If two real parts are the same, they should be sorted by imaginary part (also increasing.)

#### Examples

```
11-27i = i^2*(1+i)*(2+i)^2*(4+i)
2     = i^3*(1+i)^2
```

To be added: Examples, input output spec

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Gaussian_integer_factorizations

[is_gaussian_prime(z)?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35881/is-gaussian-primez)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271645/2913106

Comment: What about builtins?

Comment: Built-ins are ok. In my experience restricting built ins is quite subjective and frequently results in trouble=)

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate the last N digits of Graham's Number

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

---

Write a function or program that, given an integer `x`, outputs the rightmost `x` digits of [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

Rules:

- You may not hardcode the answer in
- You may not fetch the answer from an external file or library

Scoring:

- Will be tested over 100 iterations on my machine with an average time given for different `x` values
- To Be Decided... (Input would be appreciated)

Comment: Graham's number is just 3^[very large number], which always has the same last few digits; Wikipedia says they can be computed [efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Rightmost_decimal_digits).

Comment: This might be more interesting as a code-golf challenge, because it would likely be too fast to accurately time in fastest code

Answer (score 0):

## Paint the Mona Lisa in 1 KiB of code

### ** Oops, it seems that [something like this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69930/7416) has already been posted (and I didn't know about it before), but please read the last section below

This is my attempt to salvage [this challange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69232/7416) by Nathaniel, which was deleted after getting no less than 19 upvotes.

Here is a picture of da Vinci's Mona Lisa:

[image: Mona Lisa]

Your task is to reproduce the Mona Lisa in 1024 bytes or less. You will write a program or function that takes no input and loads no files, and outputs an image file.

The goal of this challenge is to produce an image that is as close as possible to the Mona Lisa above. The image must have the same resolution, and the similarity/difference will be measured by the [root-mean-square deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) (at the color component level) between the two images. That will be the only criterion for the score, but people are still free to reward interesting answers by upvoting them (as always).

Your code (program or function) must obey the following restrictions:

- The code must be no more than 1024 bytes in total (counted in UTF-8 if you use funky characters)
- It must output the image in a standard uncompressed format such as BMP or PPM; the image can be written to the standard output or directly to a file
- The image must have the same resolution as the original - 215 by 320 pixels
- The code must be completely self-contained, taking no input and loading no files (other than importing libraries, which is allowed)
- You may not use built-in or library code that implements a decompression algorithm (unzip, unlzma, jpeg decompression etc). It is fine to use such algorithms if you implement them yourself within the 1024 byte limit.
- If your language or library includes a function that outputs the Mona Lisa, you are not allowed to use that either.
- It should run deterministically, producing the same output every time.
- Your code must be runnable in Linux using freely available software

It is possible that some submissions will themselves be generated by code. If this is the case, please include in your answer the code that was used to produce your submission, and explain how it works. The above restrictions do not apply to code used to create the code, they only apply to the 1024-byte code that produces the output image.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

### TODO:

- provide code to calculate the score
- use a better-quality image?

### Duplicate?

Well, some may argue that this is a duplicate of the [Starry Night challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69930/7416), but I think it differs in at least 3 ways:

- uncompressed output
- no prewritten decompressor allowed
- UTF-8 byte count

Also, the image is not the same so it may not benefit from all the same techniques (I'm also open to using a different image altogether, such as the one from [this other deleted challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71363/7416) by Nathaniel).

If you have any other ideas how to improve the challenge, let me know.

Comment: 1) It's not clear what counts as a builtin decompression algorithm. Is RLE builtin compression? Golfing languages have it built in. 2) Our standard rules cover encoding; no need to require UTF-8. 3) A list of all the valid uncompressed formats seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a race condition

Your objective is to create program where concurrent threads race to produce a result. The program is simple. Print the sum of every element in the cartesian product of two sets.

An example of standard input would be

```
2 5 8 10 | 9 2 3 7 512 | 3 1 2 | 9 8 6 3
```

The program would then need to spin up two separate threads to calculate each result, and the first thread (and only the first thread) to complete should print "I WIN!" and the answer without using mutexes or other synchronization methods.

### Rules

- You cannot use mutexes or synchronisation
- The operation must be run concurrently
- Standard input will contain any multiple of two sets, and the program should use (no of sets / 2) threads, as well as the main thread that spins everything.
- The order of execution on the slave threads is not important
- Some failure cases where more than one thread prints "I WIN!" is acceptable, but should be a rare case *Sandbox comment: Not sure about verifying this one? or should not bother at all?*

### Sandbox comments

I saw the TCP Server question and I liked the idea of a challenge that is specifically difficult for golfing languages, and I was thinking about a few ideas for challenges that might work based specifically on parallel programming failures. I'm not sure if this one really fits the bill, hoping for suggestions to improve the challenege itself before refining the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

## A Tiny Raytracer

Your task is to make a tiny 2D raytracer to render beautiful ascii images.

### Input

Your input will be an arbitrary 2D array delimited by newlines with the following structure

```
########
#9     #
#      #
#  ##  #
#  ##  #
#      #
#    ###
########
```

The symbols are: 
`0-9` = Light source
 = Emptiness
`#` = Wall

Your expected output should look like this:

```
########
#987654#
#876543#
#76##32#
#65##00#
#543000#
#43000##
########
```

## How Light Propagates

Light will travel in a straight line from lightsources through empty space and will be completely blocked by walls. Light falls off according to this function:

```
light_intensity = clamp(floor(9 - source_intensity * ||dist_to_lightsource||), 0, 9)
```

Where `|| ||` is the euclidean norm between the cell containing the light source and the cell in question, with 1 cell = 1 unit. All light intensity values are clamped to be between `0-9`.

Light falls on an empty cell `c` whenever a straight line can be drawn from any part of `c` to the cell containing the light source without passing through a wall. For example, here I have all of the cells affected by a light source marked as `*`:

```
########       ########
####   #       ####***#
#9   #     =>  #****#  
###    #       ###****#
### ####       ### ####
```

Whenever there are multiple light sources, their contributions to the final light intensity are summed (and clamped to be between `0-9`).

For example:

```
################
#9            6#
################
```

Should yield:

```
################
#98765432223456#
################
```

## Rules

Standard code golfing rules. Input can have arbitrary size.

### Fun Optional Bonuses

- Output the result as a graphical image.
- Support light values of between 0-255 (in this case columns of the input and output will be space delimited)
- Support colors (in this case light will be denoted by a standard 24-bit hex code `0xFFFFFF`, and space delimited).

These don't give you any bonuses in the competition, but would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

## Self-decrypting code

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

The Caesar cipher is perhaps the earliest and most well known form of encryption. Here's a quick overview:

Pick a message, and a numerical encryption key. For this example, I'll pick "HELLO, WORLD" and 3, respectively.

First, convert each letter into its ASCII number:

```
H -> 72
E -> 69
L -> 76
L -> 76
O -> 79
, -> 44
[space] -> 32
W -> 87
O -> 79
R -> 82
L -> 76
D -> 68
```

Then, add the key (3) to each and convert back into a letter

```
75 -> K
72 -> H
79 -> O
79 -> O
82 -> R
47 -> /
35 -> #
90 -> Z
82 -> R
85 -> U
79 -> O
71 -> G
```

So the encrypted message is "KHOOR/#ZRUOG"

### Your task

Write a full program that is a Caesar cipher-encrypted valid English message. The program must take no input and it will output the unencrypted version of itself.

Some rules:

- The program must be at least length 2.
- The key may not be 0, 32, or 256
- All of the code must be executed (no comments to arbitrarily extend code length).
- The Linux word list will be used to judge if a message is English. Words must be separated by ASCII character 32. Words can mix uppercase and lowercase.
- Your program does not need to be written in printable ASCII.
- File I/O is allowed, but only to read the source code file.
- No other standard loopholes.

### Scoring

The submission with the **longest** message wins. Anything over 200 characters will be scored as exactly 200 characters. Ties are broken by upvotes.

Comment: I think this has a bunch of problems. The scoring doesn't make much sense why does it switch between code-challenge and pop-con? Additionally, I'm almost certain that 200 won't be that hard to reach, considering it is "valid" English to say "I am very very very ... very very sad". This also doesn't explicitly give much explanation for valid English. Do you just have to have words and spaces? Or does it need to make sense? Also, "all of the code must be executed" rules basically never work: it's too easy to get around them.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How should I deal with arbitrary-length submissions (they found a way to make it as long as possible)? As for valid sentences, maybe just words separated by spaces (but no word can be repeated). How should I prevent trivial arbitrary-length programs (because comments can be used for that).

Comment: The problem is that there are too many things that are basically the same as comments in too many different languages. What's to stop me from just inserting a giant numeric/string literal in my code that don't get printed? What about repeating `;` in a C program? What about languages that don't even really read their source code like [lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage)? I feel like if your challenge breaks because of comment like things, it's sort of doomed to be broken.

Comment: What constitutes a "*valid English message*"? What modulus operations are permitted?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Any modulus operations that don't bring the message back to itself and aren't the exact difference between lowercase and uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

## Manual MD5

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing)

Given a string, calculate its MD5 sum without using any built-in MD5 library functions. [An overview of the algorithm is here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm)

*(I'm going to actually summarize the algorithm before I post it. Until then, it's still unfinished.)*

Input is an ASCII string or byte stream with any reasonable length (I won't run an entire novel through your algorithm, for example).

Output the hex value of the resultant hash as a string.

Code golf, so shortest code wins. Standard loopholes are banned.

Comment: You add the tags by adding `[tag:code-golf]` (and the others) to the body of your post.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, include a description of the algorithm in the challenge body. Requiring external resources for a challenge is discouraged.

Comment: 1. "*Given a string, calculate its MD5 sum*" is underspecified. In many languages nowadays, a string is a sequence of Unicode characters; MD5 is defined over sequences of octets, so to talk about the MD5 sum of a string you first have to define its encoding in octets. 2. Output format?

Comment: I clarified as ASCII string now in the input section. Should I mention that at the top, as well?

Comment: I think so. It's a one word addition and it avoids people wandering mentally off track.

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate the number of consecutive 0's at the end of n!

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

---

Simply put, write a program or function that takes `n` and returns the number of consecutive 0's at the end of `n!`

---

**Examples**

```
Input: 12
Output: 2
```

---

```
Input: 12345
Output: 3082
```

---

```
Input: 100000
Output: 24999
```

Comment: I think this might be a dupe.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Do you have a link to the duplicate problem?

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/694/31625) is extremely similar.

Comment: This proposal would be similar to finding the _position_ of the last nonzero digit, but it's not similar to the linked challenge, which finds the _value_ of the last nonzero digit

Answer (score 0):

## How many pixels are in each ASCII char?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program or function taking a single printable ASCII character as input that outputs how many pixels it takes to display that character to the screen.

Input can be taken by any reasonable method, including reading from a file, STDIN, or function argument. Input from a variable hardcoded into the program is not reasonable.

Output may by given by any reasonable method, including writing to a file and STDOUT. Extraneous output is permitted as long as the result remains unambiguous.

"Printable ASCII character" is defined as a character within the codepoints 32-126, inclusive.

A pixel counts as part of a character if the pixel is non-white after the character is written to a white screen.

The required font is Times New Roman, 20pt.

Do not hardcode the result.

#### Reference Solution: (JavaScript)

```js
//create a canvas to display the character
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
canvas.width = 100
canvas.height = 100
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

//make the canvas white
context.fillStyle = "white"
context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

//make the text black and set the font
context.fillStyle = "black"
context.font = "20pt Times New Roman"

//ask for the char
var char = prompt("Enter your ASCII char")
   
//draw the char
context.fillText(char,50,50)

//get the canvas pixel data
var pixelData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100).data
var pixelCount = 0
for(var i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i+=4) {

    //if the pixel isn't white, increment the counter
 if(pixelData[i] != 255 || pixelData[i+1] != 255 || pixelData[i+2] != 255) pixelCount++
}
alert(pixelCount)
```

Comment: Is there any specific font that should be used?

Comment: you should probably set a specified font (Times New Roman, Arial), to make answers more comparable. If not, you should probably say the font should have been made before this challenge was posted

Comment: @Downgoat actually on second thought, languages that can't output Times New Roman probably don't have the features to compete in this challenge anyway. I'll make 20pt Times New Roman the required font.

Comment: I wonder if any other algorithms exist that are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

### Self-identification before golfing

Since golfed code is harder to read, answers often contain an less golfed version. There are a number of potential golfing transformations depending on the language, so you may be able to score more highly using a more traditional language. Some examples of golfing transformations:

- Removal of spaces, tabs and/or newlines
- Removal of disambiguating parentheses
- Removal of braces around single controlled statements
- Conversion from statements to comma operator
- Removal of explicit return statements
- Renaming identifiers

Your challenge is to write a program or function that can identify an ungolfed version of itself. Scoring is based on the number of golfing transformations that can be recognised. The submission must be capable of identifying all "original" code that is itself capable of self-identification (at least one such code must exist). Each supported transformation scores 1 point, but there are also bonus points available:

- 1 bonus point if the transformation can be repeated multiple times
- 1 bonus point of the program rejects at least one invalid transformation of itself (e.g. white space added inside a keyword)
- 1 bonus point if the program only accepts valid transformations of itself
- 1 bonus point if the transformation shortened the code (so if you only supported renaming a 1-letter variable to another letter, you would not qualify)
- 1 bonus bonus point if in addition the transformed program recognises the original program as a transformation of itself

Example: A submission accepts the name of another program as a command-line parameter. It opens itself using its own name hard-coded into itself. It recognises the following transformations:

- A change to the hard-coded file name (3 points, as there is only one file)
- A change to the amount of space between words (5 points, as there are no invalid transformations to reject)
- A change to the names of its variables (4 points, as it doesn't check whether the variables are renamed consistently or to keywords)

Total score: 12 points.

In the event of a tie on score, shortest code wins.

Tags: code-golf, quine

Comment: This is hopelessly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

In this challenge you are supposed to output a grid 10x10 with numbers from 00 to 99 (each number once) following this rules:

- Number 00 must be on the bottom row
- Number 99 must be on the upper row
- In the output each number must be sepparated by spaces and must have two digits (that is including 0's when needed for the first 10 numbers)
- Output must be random
- It must be solved within reasonable time

I'm having an issue trying to define *random* and *reasonable time* here and would like some help with it.
Thanks.

Comment: Define *random* as 'Each of the possible permutations must have an equal probability of being the output'. For *reasonable time* I don't think you need a definition - especially since your challenge is only 100 numbers, so it should be perfectly doable unless your algorithm works in O(n!).

Comment: @sanchises I find that asking for equal probability is too strong, since there's no way to prove that one of those algorythm has equal probability.

Comment: Of course, a formal proof is not always easy. However, an intuitive result should be enough for most applications, and if people have difficulty with that, you can always use one of the [algorithms described at the Wikpedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation), e.g. Knuth shuffling. I was wondering though, is there a motivation behind the challenge, or is just something you cooked up?

Answer (score 0):

**@Sandbox:**

- Not sure if [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) is correct here.
- Do I need test cases for this? They will make this very lengthy.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)

## Find the structs!

## The Challenge

Given a piece of C-code, add a `/*` before and a `*/` after every top-level structure definition that you find. You may not do this for structures that are defined inside other structures.

- A structure can be identified by the `struct` keyword followed by an identifier, an opening `{`, some alphanumeric characters inside the structure and a closing `};`.
- A structure identifier will only consist of alphanumeric characters.
- One structure may also contain other structures with an unlimited depth.
- Comments and whitespaces may appear anywhere in the code and have no effect. `//` starts a single line comment and code enclosed in `/*` and `*/` is a multiline comment.
- You can't rely on a specific indentation style.
- A structure will not contain any braces `{}` that are not part of another structure definition.
- There can be multiple top-level structures in the input. You have to consider them all.
- The input will only contain printable ASCII and newlines.

## Example

So the output for

```c
int z;
struct example1 /* comment here */  {
    int x; // struct comment {int x;};
    struct nested
    {
        char* s;
        int* y;
    };
};
int y;

//struct { };

struct example2{int x;};
```

would be

```c
int z;
/*struct example /* comment here */  {
    int x; // struct comment {int x;};
    struct nested
    {
        char* s;
        int* y;
    };
};*/
int y;

//struct { };

/*struct example2{int x;};*/
```

## Rules

- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: I think this has some problems, as most questions that say "Given some C code do...", with what counts as valid. What about things like trigraphs, or macros or... ?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman So it would be fine, when I limit the possible code-contents to a certain subset of C like I did for the struct contents?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not well versed enough in C grammar to be able to say for sure that that'll be enough.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thought about this and I actually don't need all that C-syntax stuff. Just came from the origin of this, but it's no really needed. Should be clear now.

Comment: Please work on your spelling before posting this, if you do.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You can't fault OP for speaking ESL; this is why anyone can edit posts on SE.

Comment: @cat That's actually wrong. You can't suggest edits on meta, and this answer isn't CW, so I'm not able to edit this. If you'd like to confirm, take any of your accounts with less than the required rep, go to meta, and try to edit something. It doesn't let you.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'm aware there are no suggested edits on Meta, because that would mean *more*, *more clogged* review queues for popular sites. I meant when the challenge is posted which is the only time small grammar things will matter anyhow, and I tend to be the type to fix that stuff.

Comment: @cat Oh, I see. I thought you meant I should edit the Sandbox post, which... I can't. I've been told several times to "just edit it!" on various Metas where I don't have permission; I have yet to be told "edit it when this is on main" :P

Answer (score 0):

## Matrix Multiplication

This is a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge in which we will be multiplying matrices.

**Input**:

- an `n x m` matrix, `A`
- an `m x p` matrix, `B`
- optional:

  - `n`, `m`, and `p`

Input may be in any convenient fashion in order to reduce/eliminate the need to parse input. In particular, it may be given via function argument. The matrix dimensions may be taken as input or may be deduced from the actual matrix input.

**Output**:

The [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) of the two matrices. That is, output the `n x p` matrix `C` such that `A * B = C`.

**Scoring**

Your score will be the average of the sum of times your program takes to multiply several test cases *on my computer*.

Basically, I:

- Time your entry for each test case
- Add up all the times
- Repeat the above steps several/many times
- Average all the sums
- That average is your score

**Rules and Restrictions**

- Built in array/vector/matrix multiplication functions are disallowed. If you have to ask if a built-in is allowed, it probably isn't (but please ask anyways).

  - However, once the test cases are up, I would like to see how MatLab compares to the given entries
- Entries in `A` and `B` will be standard 16 bit signed integer. Entries in `C` will fit in 32 bit signed integers.
- Matrix size/dimensions should be limited by mainly by my available memory.
- The size of test cases is not yet determined. It will depend on the speed and memory requirements of entries. I will of course try my utmost to be fair.
- I have 8G of RAM and an AMD64 cpu.
- Languages must be freely available on linux. Please include instructions on how to compile/execute your code.

**Notes**

I'm really not sure how big the matrices will be, but I'm expecting dimensions in the 100's or 1000's.

Comment: I think at slightly above 10000x10000 matrices you will run out of RAM, considering you'd have to store three of these matrices. MATLAB can multiply matrices of that size on my machine (similar specs) with a time of still only about 45 seconds. So I think memory is probably going to be the main limiting factor=) (And I do not think that anything's going to be much faster than BLAS)

Comment: @flawr I think 45sec would be long enough to get accurate timings. Also my machine is probably slower than yours and I doubt any entries will beat MatLab's time. If you think memory will still be a problem, I have no problem using 16 bit integers instead of 32 bit.

Comment: 1. Without knowing more about the test cases and the CPU it's going to be hard to optimise, because the sizes you're talking are roughly where the cutoff for naïve being worse than Strassen lies. 2. Can assembly answers use SIMD instructions (SSE etc.) or are they banned built-ins?

Answer (score 0):

## Iterated Matrix Multiplication

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Given an `nxn` matrix `A`, an `nx1` matrix `X`, and a list `L` of ordered pairs in `[0,n)x[0,n)`, determine if there exists some integer `k>=0` such that, with `B=A^k*X`, for all `(D,E)` in `L`, `B[D]<B[E]`.

**Why it's possible:** Every entry of the natural number power of a general matrix can be expressed via sums of multiples of powers of the matrix's eigenvalues, like `2^k+4*6^k-10*3^k`, and for any two such expressions, there will always be some `k` beyond which one term dominates the expression, and the sign of their difference can no longer change, so one way to solve the problem would be to calculate that `k`.

**Test cases:**

```
[[1,2],[2,3]],[3,4],[(0,1)] -> Yes (k=0)
[[1,2],[2,3]],[3,4],[(1,0)] -> No
[[1,2],[2,3]],[4,3],[(1,0)] -> Yes (k=0)
[[1,2],[2,3]],[4,3],[(0,1)] -> Yes (k=1)
[[1,-2],[2,-3]],[3,4],[(1,0)] -> Yes (k=1)
[[-1,-2],[2,-3]],[3,4],[(1,0)] -> Yes (k=2)
[[-1,-2],[2,-3]],[3,4],[(1,0),(0,1)] -> No
```

Comment: 1. For [tag:fastest-code] you need to describe how you will measure it, selecting a test size which is large enough to give meaningful differences but small enough to be feasible. That probably means that you need to write a reference implementation or three (trying difference approaches). 2. For floating point questions, you need to do some numerical analysis to determine on what range of input it's feasible to write a correct program, and then guarantee that the input will be within that range. 3. You need to think about what level of library support is fair.

Answer (score 0):

### Colorize!

In Ruby, the `colorize` gem allows you to output text to the terminal in pretty colors:

[image: Blue, bold text saying "This is a box"]

It uses the [ANSI color standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to tell the terminal how to color things, then trusts that the terminal will do the right thing. For this challenge, you can too.

What you'll do is take a a pair of lidts of strings, in whatever format you want. For example, if you wanted comma-separated values:

```
+-----+,| box |,+-----+
red,blue,red
```

The first list is what you'll be colorizing. The second list is a list of color names that are the same as the ones in the Wikipedia article. You'll colorize each string from the first list with the respective color from the second. The two lists will always have the same number of items, and the second will only ever contain valid color names. The strings in the first will only contain valid, printable ASCII characters.

And apply those colors -- as given by the ANSI standard linked above -- to the text, printing each string on its own line. For example, with this (heavily ungolfed) code:

```
#to be written
```

you'd get this:

[picture of result]

You may not use any libraries built to do this, and the standard loopholes are disallowed.

---

I'm thinking of adding extra credit for bolding/doing multiple things at once. Is that a good idea?

Aside from that, how is the rest of the challenge?

---

To-do list:

- Copy the list from Wikipedia to here
- Add pictures, demo code
- Add that you have to change the color back to default at the end

Comment: The comma separated thing seems unnecessary, in most languages this just adds a boring `split(',')` call. You also probably want to only allow printable ASCII in the body of the strings (or at least put some restriction otherwise stuff can get pretty hairy). In addition you should explain what is necessary to know from the ANSI standard in your question body.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I linked the relevant part and stated "ANSI color standard" when it was first mentioned. What input format would you suggest that can deliver a set of lines to colorized and a set of colors to use?

Comment: Just say what they are: a list of strings and a list of colours. The link doesn't matter: if Wikipedia is down or they change that page so it doesn't help here then I can't answer your question without guessing what you mean. Also, the reason I said printable ASCII is that some ASCII is still hard to deal with. What about control characters, etc.?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Oh, I see. I'll update it to have "input of two lists in whatever format you want" and "printable ASCII characters only". As for requiring Wikipedia to be up, I'll copy and paste it when I have time. However, note that ANSI's standards are available online, and Googling "ANSI color standard" yields their website as well. Wikipedia is far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

## Random Wikipedia Browsing

Here's a short one for you.  Create a program or function prints or returns the title of a random Wikipedia page (similar to Alt + x functionality)

**Rules:**

- Program or function will take no input
- Program or function will print to STDOUT (or nearest equivalent) or return only the page name. I don't care about trailing spaces or newlines.  Preceding spaces or new lines are disallowed
- Program or function may not access a list of Wikipedia page names stored within a local file.
- There is no requirement to use English language Wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org)
- Page must be chosen (psuedo) randomly

For reference, here is a [link to the Wikipedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).  Shortest program or function in bytes wins.

Comment: Bash: `xdg-open http://bit.ly/19UDVJs` (I think it's `open`). That Bitly link points to [the Random Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) link, which redirects to a random page. Wouldn't be hard to find a shorter URL, either.

Comment: Aww man, I had no idea that existed, guess it makes this pretty trivial

Comment: Yep. Though if the language's builtins don't support automatic handling of redirects, it might be more challenging.

Comment: Could I disallow using that link?

Comment: I dunno, to be honest. I'm not very good at writing challenges.

Comment: [Relevant chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29013714#29013714), this challenge is trival

Comment: @wnnmaw the Random Page is often used for [wiki-racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikirace). It's pretty fun. You can do either shortest distance (pages traversed), or fastest time. Maybe you could make this into a King of the Hill challenge to write a bot that wiki-races against other bots?

Answer (score 0):

### Spiral text

Write a function or program that given a text with one or more characters in it outputs the text as a square spiral. The first letter of the text must be the center of the spiral and then all the characters must follow a clockwise spiral pattern as follow, striping all white spaces:

```
           789[10]
           612[11]
           543[12]
              [13]
```

Example

```
Input: Hello World!
Output:

               ORLD
               WHE!
               OLL
```

The text could be any length. Please validate with the following texts:

```
Once upon a time
```

Expected output:

```
o   n   a   t
p   o   n   i
u   e   c   m
            e


Tyger Tyger, burning bright, In the forests of the night;
```

Expected output:

```
g   h   t   ;           
i   i   g   h   t,  I   n
n   r   y   g   e   r   t
e   b   t   t   y   ,   h
h   g   r   e   g   b   e
t   n   i   n   r   u   f
f   o   t   s   e   r   o
```

The minimung length of the input text is one character.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Note: Somewhat similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75446/draw-spiral-words)

Comment: Test cases are more useful if you also include the expected output. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner yay! Doing that

Comment: Also having to support the empty string seems like an annoying special case that isn't likely to add anything interesting to most answers, so I'd personally probably let the input have at least one character, but that's your call.

Comment: When you say "somewhat similar": why should I not vote to close it as a duplicate? It seems that the only difference is a reflection in the leading diagonal, which I would class as trivial.

Comment: @PeterTaylor First of all the other question doesn't have any answer and it is a bit old so maybe now this question can get a little more audience now. Secondly the other question add "The characters can spiral into previous characters" that this doesn't add to the specs so I think they are different questions.

Comment: Ok, the other question is horrible. This is actually more like various spiralling numbers questions, with the main difference being that it spirals outwards rather than inwards.

Answer (score 0):

### Is this a helpful starting layout?

My computer has a Patience-style card game installed on it. It takes two packs of cards, removes the Aces, shuffles them, and deals 8 cards.

In order to maintain my 100% perfect completion record, I want as helpful a starting layout as possible. Deuces are immediately playable, so they are helpful cards. However other cards can only be played on cards of descending rank and opposite colour, which means that cards of the same rank and colour unhelpfully clog up the layout.

The challenge is to write a program or function which accepts a string or list of eight cards and outputs a truthy or falsy value. Cards are identified by their rank, which is one of the characters `23456789TJQK`, and their suit, which is one of the characters `CDHS`. (Note that using numbers 10-13 for the rank is not an acceptable input.) For a layout to be helpful there must be at least one Deuce of any rank, and (except Deuces) there must not be any pairs of cards with the same rank and colour. Examples:

```
4H7STHTD5C5D2HQS -> unhelpful because of two red Tens
TD8S4CKC4HKD5S5H -> unhelpful because of no Deuces
2H7SJH3S4HKS7H3H -> helpful layout
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins.

Comment: At first I thought this was a request for help, not the setting for a problem. You'll want to add what those inputs mean, what "a helpful layout" means, in detail.

Comment: As I understand, this can be solved by checking if the string contains `2` and its chunks of two are distinct, which seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @xnor Not quite distinct, since a) you have to ignore the chunks that contain 2 and b) H==D and S==C for the purposes of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve for the Operators

In this challenge, you will be given a bunch of numbers and an answer. Your job is to find a sequence of operators that will successfully solve this equation. **Use the numbers in the order that they are given**

Operators: +, -, *, /

For example,

Numbers given: 2, 6, 8, 4, 5

Answer: 9

```
2__3__8__4__5 = 9
```

The program should find which operators can be used in the blanks to make the equation true. **Remember Order of Operations Matters (PEMDAS)**

Output:

```
2*3-8/4+5 = 9
```

**Only 1 solution is needed per problem**

### Rules

1. No built-in math functions beyond operators.
2. Must Follow Order of Operations
3. Must give one correct output.
4. Least Number of Bytes Wins.

#### Examples:

Numbers: 4, 4, 4, 4

Answer: 0

```
4 - 4 + 4 + 4 = 0
```

Numbers: 1, 8, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3

Answer: -35

```
1*8+6-4*5*2-3*3 = -35
```

Numbers: 1, -2

Answer: 3

```
1--2 = 3
```

Comment: In many languages, this will just be "find the cartesian product of `+-*/` repeated as many times as there are blanks with itself, insert them over the blanks and call eval". It's fine if you want that, but it seems somewhat, uh, boring?

Comment: 4 - 4 + 4 + 4 = 8

Answer (score 0):

**Make a times table sheet**

The challenge is to make an ascii art version of a times table sheet.

Look at the following:

[image: times tables].

Your answer should have the same layout as this table:

- You should not include the title or the footer or worry about colors. Black and white is fine.
- The times tables lines in each box should be randomly ordered.
- You should include all the horizontal and vertical lines in the image (except in the header and footer).
- The equals signs should be aligned in each column as in the example  above.
- It should be in ASCII art.

I am not worried about the precise spacing as long as the layout is as specified.
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: no ascii art for me?

Comment: @KennyLau I could make it ASCII art if people love that.

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge

Create a factor tree from a number. A factor tree will take a number > 1, `n`, and find 2 numbers that multiply together to equal `n` that are greater than 1. Then, it will repeat for the factors until every section reaches a number that does. Then it will output the last numbers.

For example:

[image]

## Examples:

Input: `n = 20`

Graph(This is not the output):

[image]

Output: `2x2x2x3`

Input: `n = 54`

Output:`2x3x3x3`

Input: `n = 72`

Output: `3x3x2x2x2`

Input: `n = 2`

Output: `2`

## Scoring

Shortest bytes wins.

Comment: I think you mean a `factor tree`, not factorial. That is very different.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ yes that is what i meant. Thank you

Comment: Would it be more interesting if i had the output be the tree instead of the numbers?

Comment: yeah, I think the numbers is probably a dupe. Plus, it would be more fun/hard. (hard isn't bad)

Comment: I recommend having output be a image/ascii art, though that needs more specifications.

Comment: As it stands, this is a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/factorize-me

Answer (score 0):

## Inverse Square Probability

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

It's a fairly well-known fact that the sum of the reciprocals of squares is equal to pi squared divided by 6. That is,

[image: Basel Problem]

This is the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and was solved by Euler in 1735. I was thinking about generating a random patchwork of squares and trying to decide how to weight the probabilities of different square sizes, when it occurred to me that I could use this fact and make the probability of choosing a square's size be the inverse of its size.

For instance, if I pick a random point on the interval `[0..pi^2/6)`, then based on the point I pick, `r`, I can translate it to a square size in the following manner (all numbers rounded to 3 decimal places):

```
0     <= r < 1     => s = 1
1     <= r < 1.25  => s = 2
1.25  <= r < 1.361 => s = 3
1.361 <= r < 1.424 => s = 4
1.424 <= r < 1.464 => s = 5
...
```

Your program or function should work for any input within the limits of your language (for instance, floating point precision, lack of built-in bignum capabilities, etc). Input will always be `0 <= r < pi^2/6`.

### Test Cases

```
{to be added}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ASCII Hulls

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

---

## Input

A string containing a rectangle made up of *m* rows of *n* characters, separated by newlines. Apart from an optional trailing newline (which you may choose), the string must contain nothing else.

All the characters will be printable ASCII (including space). So ASCII characters 32 to 176 inclusive.

The dimensions *m* and *n* will not be specified in the input. They will both be in the range 1 to 80 inclusive.

## Output

A string containing the same rectangle but with the convex hull of each non-space character filled with that character, higher ASCII values overwriting lower ones.

Overwriting does not prevent a character from contributing to the convex hull. For each character, the convex hull is defined based on the locations of that character *before* any overwriting.

## Details

The rectangle of characters forms a grid of *m* squares by *n* squares. The vertices of the convex hull for a given character are the centres of the squares containing that character (apart from any in the interior of the convex hull). All squares whose centre is on the convex hull or in its interior become that character (until any overwriting).

[image: Outline showing convex hull] [image: Filled convex hull]

Equivalently you can use the top left corner instead of the centre (or any other point in the square) provided it is consistent. This will give the same output.

## Test cases

#### Input followed by output in a single code block

```
P    
   P
 P  

P    
 PPP
 P
```

```
C    C

      G    G
    C    C

   G    G

CCCCCC
  CCCCC
   CCCGGGGGG
    CGGGGGG
    GGGGGG
   GGGGGG
```

```
 W    Z
X      X


Y      Y
 W    Z

 W    Z
XXXXXXZX
 W    Z
 W    Z 
YYYYYYZY
 W    Z
```

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I don't understand what the "convex hull" is here. Could you give an example?

Comment: @NathanMerrill It's a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) I think.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I added some test cases to visualise it

Comment: @NathanMerrill I added a diagram which hopefully sums it up better

Comment: How do you decide if a letter is within the hull? For example, it seems like the first should be `P` / `PPPP` / `_PP`, because part of the square between the midpoints of each letter is crossed.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes `All squares whose centre is on the convex hull or in its interior become that character` so it isn't enough for part of the square to be crossed - the *centre* of the square has to be on or within the convex hull.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes more sense.r

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble deciding for this one, but apart from the fact that there's multiple hulls and ASCII parsing/writing involved, is the core of the challenge any different from existing convex hull challenges?

Comment: @Sp3000 unless the need to keep track of where the initial characters were while doing the overwriting for other characters adds anything in terms of golfing challenge, then I guess this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

## Triangle Rasterization

I don't know if this is the right word for this, but here goes...

Given a triangle with a height and a width, you can convert it into squares by counting any square that the triangle occupies as a whole square. Your task is to calculate the area of this 'rasterized' triangle.

Your program should take two **positive integers** representing the height and width of a triangle and output the area of its 'rasterized' version. This should always be an integer.

No builtins are allowed, if there are any.

### An example

[image: What I'm actually talking about.]
This is a 6x4 triangle. The red area is the actual inside of the triangle, and the blue area is added on during the 'rasterization'. The total are of the red and the blue is 16. So, given `6` and `4` as inputs, your program must output `16`, with or without a trailing newline.

## Test cases

```
 input     output
 1, 1      1
 1, 2      2
 1, 3      3
 2, 2      3
 6, 4      16
 63, 47    1512
```

As you can probably tell, this is slightly larger than half the area of the enclosing rectangle, and gets more accurate for larger sizes.

Your program should preferably run in under a minute, but the answer with the shortest number of bytes will win.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Are you sure about the test case `63, 47`? I make it 1535.

Comment: @PeterTaylor while fiddling around with a solution I made, I think this error comes from rounding poorly. When I tried adding 1 to each column with a non-integer value and then flooring (I believe this is equivalent to taking the ceiling) I got your answer, but when I tried adding `.5` to each value and then flooring I got the value the OP got. For reference: [ceil](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sms%2BJ%2adcFQ%21sIJSeQ&input=63%2C47&debug=0) and [flop](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sms%2B%2adcFQ.5SeQ&input=63%2C47&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

### "45-degree rotation" of a square matrix

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

---

### Introduction

Suppose we have a square matrix with odd sidelength, like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4
```

Let's divide it into nested layers as follows:

```
0 1 2 3 4
 +-----+
5|6 7 8|9
 | +-+ |
0|1|2|3|4
 | +-+ |
5|6 7 8|9
 +-----+
0 1 2 3 4
```

The `n`th layer, counting from the center, contains `8*(n-1)` cells, and we 
rotate it `n-1` steps in the clockwise direction:

```
0 5 0 1 2
 +-----+
5|1 6 7|3
 | +-+ |
0|6|2|8|4
 | +-+ |
1|7 8 3|9
 +-----+
2 3 4 9 4
```

Now our original matrix has been "rotated by 45 degrees", in a sense:

```
0 5 0 1 2
5 1 6 7 3
0 6 2 8 4
1 7 8 3 9
2 3 4 9 4
```

Namely, if this operation is applied twice, the result is a 90-degree rotation.

### The task

Your input is an `n×n` matrix of single-digit integers, where `n` is odd, in any reasonable format.
Your output is the 45-degree rotation of this matrix, as defined above.

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

### Test cases

```
[[3]] -> [[3]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] -> [[4,1,2],[7,5,3],[8,9,6]]
[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[0,1,2,3,4]] -> [[0,5,0,1,2],[5,1,6,7,3],[0,6,2,8,4],[1,7,8,3,9],[2,3,4,9,4]]
[[1,0,0,2,0,0,3],[0,1,0,2,0,3,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[4,4,4,5,0,0,0],[4,4,4,4,0,0,0],[4,4,4,4,0,6,7],[4,4,4,4,0,8,9]] -> [[4,0,0,1,0,0,2],[4,4,0,1,0,2,0],[4,4,4,1,2,0,0],[4,4,4,5,3,3,3],[4,4,4,0,0,0,0],[4,4,0,6,0,0,0],[4,0,8,9,7,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## KOTH Screeps Fighting AI [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

[Screeps](http://screeps.com) is an MMO for programmers (not a regular MMO, this is not modding, but rather the only way to play) where you program creeps. I want to make sure one more time: this is not hacking or modding, this is the only way you play the game. It has a builtin IDE that is always present.

This is your job: With 1550 energy, spawn an army of creeps to fight other player's armies. Your goal is to destroy the other team's spawn.

### Specifications

- Each team will start with 0 creeps and it's own spawn.
- The team number will be hardcoded.
- The spawns will be named Spawn1 and Spawn2, corresponding to each player's team
- The room controller will be at level 8 and you will not have to worry about upgrading it.
- Each creep will display an emoji chosen to represent it's team using `creep.say()`. This is so that members of the two teams can distinguished.

### Rules

- Not all creeps have to fight. Some can gather energy, build walls, etc.
- Building structures is allowed. This includes walls, ramparts, towers, etc.

**This is under construction! Please comment if you know how to improve this challenge!**

Comment: I recall that in your purely energy gathering Screeps challenge, the example room could be used that did not require paying or creating an account. What is the situation with this new challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## Serialize and Deserialize a Binary Tree!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A coding website, [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/faq/#binary-tree), has a method to serialize a binary tree.

Serialize means making a binary tree linear.

For example, we have:

```
[1,[[2],[3,4,5]]]

    1
   / \
  2   3
     / \
    4   5
```

First, we fill the missing places with `0`:

```
      1
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  2       3
 / \     / \
0   0   4   5
```

Then read out all the lines from top to bottom:

```
->      1
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
->  2       3
   / \     / \
-> 0   0   4   5

[1,2,3,0,0,4,5]
```

Let's look at another example:

```
   1
    \
     2
    /
   3
```

Fill the missing places with `0`:

```
   1
  / \
 0   2
    / \
   3   0
```

Note that `0` cannot have any child.

Therefore, this tree is serialized as `[1,0,2,3,0]`.

Your task is to write two programs/functions, one to serialize, one to deserialize.

### Specs

- They may share code.
- The binary tree will only contain positive integers.
- A node in the binary tree is represented by `[name,left_child,right_child]`.
- You may **not** pre-fill the binary tree with `0`s.
- `[1,0,2,3,0,0,0]` is invalid.
- Unlike the website given, `[1,0,2,3]` is invalid.

## Notes

- Subset of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/339/binary-tree-encoding), but this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) instead.

Answer (score 0):

### String covering

Given a target string and a list of fragment strings, determine whether the target string can be formed by concatenating fragments, allowing overlaps. Each fragment can be used any number of times.

Example:

```
cataract, [tar, car, tar, act, rat] -> True

cataract
cat
  tar
     act
```

---

Is this a dupe? It's hard to search for. Is it too similar to [Imposters at the Zoo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70289/20260)?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79098/is-this-uniquely-concatenable), [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47249/longest-common-substring).

Comment: This challenge differs from zoo due to the fact that you can't "hide" mismatching parts, so I think it's fine. Not sure if there are any other potential dupes though. (also, I don't think Leaky's "related"s are *that* related)

Comment: Just to double check, does "Each fragment can be used any number of times." mean that `cancan, [can] -> True`?

Comment: I see a typo: "cat" isn't in the list but "tar" is twice

Answer (score 0):

## What can I build? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### The Rules

Today I have decided to make geometric shapes out of toothpicks and gumdrops! However, I have a limited supply, so you have to figure out what I can build.
I will give you an input in the format `m n`, where m is toothpicks (edges) and n is gumdrops (vertices.) Your output should be, in any output format of your choice, all 3D geometric shapes such that the amount of edges=m and the amount of vertices=n. The list of 3D geometric shapes you will  use is this: 
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ev3commander/e3acb95665c44e825ee33671601a49d3)

- You may **NOT** access the Internet.
- No builtins relating to geometry or solids
- This is code golf, so shortest code wins.
- For no solids and invalid input, output nothing

## Examples

In: `3 2`
Out: `<empty>`

In: `CodeGolf123` Out: `<empty>`
In: `12 6` Out (Bonus): `{regular tetrahedron,unit equilateral square pyramid,unit equilateral triangular dipyramid,unit equilateral triangular prism,unit equilateral pentagonal pyramid,regular octahedron}` Out (Regular): `{regular octahedron}`
`

Comment: The first 3 rules can be deleted, as they're ppcg defaults

Comment: Not the first...

Comment: I think this would work better with _1_ solid with exactly n and m edges and sides.

Comment: How about doing that, but having this as a bonus?

Comment: 1. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Ditch the stuff about the external file: the overhead to load it and the overhead generated by requiring it to be UTF-8 mean that no-one would want to use it anyway. 2. "*No builtins*" literally bans people from using any language. Specify what built-ins are banned. 3. Make the data available in a usable format: i.e. a text file hosted on gist.github.com or pastebin. 4. The bonus is a no-brainer: a 10% saving for changing two `==` to `<=`. Either make it compulsory or remove it entirely, because as it stands it's just complication.

Comment: @petertaylor: I  am currently on a phone so I can't put a gist...

Comment: There are **a lot** of shapes in that gist. Some of them are specified in different formats. If they're all to be supported it would be nice to have a standard format to represent them. Also some of these shapes specify different edge lengths. Will the challenge assume all edges are length 1 or will you potentially need to break toothpicks and keep track of the remaining pieces?

Comment: @Poke 1. Will fix 2. Irrelevant-- you have all sorts of toothpicks, some miniscule and others huge.

Answer (score 0):

## Primary Chances

Write a program that lists all possible outcomes for a general election with any number of candidates.

Rules:

- Your answer must output how many states each candidate won in any format.
- Candidates can have any name.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard loopholes are forbidden, and shortest code wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Sort 2D points by Sierpiński curve order

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

---

[ WORK IN PROGRESS]

---

#### Input

A collection of distinct 2D points in the range [0,1] X [0,1].

#### Output

An ordered collection of the same 2D points, meeting the criteria for Sierpiński curve order.

## Sierpiński curve order

- The points are in the order that the [Sierpiński curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve) would pass through them.
- The order is cyclic - it does not matter which point is first.
- The order may be clockwise or anticlockwise/counterclockwise, provided it is consistent.
- The point at the centre of the range, (0.5, 0.5), may fall into any triangular quarter of the range, provided it is in the correct order among other points in that quarter. Similarly for all other points where both coordinates have finite binary expansion.

Although the curve is infinitely long and fills the unit square, it is arranged in a convenient shape that allows ordering points by calculating only a finite number of iterations. For example, if there are 4 points, one in each triangular quarter of the square, then they can be ordered based only on this information as the curve fills one triangular quarter before moving on to the next so the exact position without that quarter is not relevant.

---

## Sandbox questions

- Should ambiguous points be allowed to fall in any direction, or should I impose that they always fall left rather than right and up rather than down? Or just insist that the solution choose a consistent direction rule?
- Can I assume that any three points that can be described by floating point variables can be ordered in a finite number of subdivisions? I'm pretty sure but welcome a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

## **Find ALL Longest Common Substrings**

Unlike "Longest Common Substring" algorithm which returns just one string, or the length of it. This algorithm returns a score after taking all separate longest common substrings into account.

This program returns the score of how similar one string is to another according to the following rules:

1. isolate only the longest (non-overlaping) matching substrings.
2. score every longest substring found with this formula: (substring.length / ((string1.length + string2.length) / 2)) * substring.length
3. sum the scores and return.

**STEP 1 Example:**

```
string1 = ABCD

string2 = ZBCA
```

Deconstructing string1: (list of substring in order)

```
ABCD

ABC

AB

A (also found in string2)

BCD

BC (also found in string2)

B (also found in string2 but ignored - part of a longer substring)

CD

C (also found in string2 but ignored - part of a longer substring)

D

Matches: A, BC
```

**STEP 2 Example:** (substring.length / ((string1.length + string2.length) / 2)) * substring.length

```
A: (1/((4+4)/2)) * 1 = .25

BC: (2/((4+4)/2)) * 2 = 1
```

**Step 3 Example:**

```
.25 + 1 = 1.25, Return 1.25
```

Here's an example of longer strings of variable length:

```
string1 = Approximate This

string2 = Appropriate That Thing

Matches: Appro, i, ate Th,  Thi

Appro: (5/((16+22)/2)) * 5 = 1.3157894736842105263157894736842

ate Th: (6/((16+22)/2)) * 6 = 1.8947368421052631578947368421053

i: (1/((16+22)/2)) * 1 = 0.05263157894736842105263157894737

 Thi: (4/((16+22)/2)) * 4 = 0.47368421052631578947368421052632

Return: 4.1052631578947368421052631578948
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fizzbuzz for tensorflow

Since I was a new and naive user, I posted this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80493/deep-learning-fizzbuzz?noredirect=1#comment197826_80493). In one day it got over 25 upvotes but was shut down for being too broad. Clearly there is community interest -- so by the suggestion of @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ I'll try it again in the sandbox. I'd really like to see some of the answers here, so I appreciate any help you can give turning this question into a proper submission.

Original text copied below:

---

Inspired by the [job-interview with Joel Grus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80493/deep-learning-fizzbuzz?noredirect=1#comment197826_80493), the goal of this challenge is to write a [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) (or other deep/machine learning) program that *learns* [Fizzbuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Programming_interviews) and correctly prints out the answers to the positive integers less than 1000.

You can assume there are files named `train.csv` and `test.csv` and each contain a sorted list of sequential integers and the fizzbuzz answer:

```
 ...
 100, buzz
 101, 101
 102, fizz
 103, 103
 104, 104
 105, buzz
 ...
 150000, fizzbuzz
```

`test.csv` spans 1-1000 and `train.csv` spans 1001-150000.

### Rules

1. You must not hard-code the rules to Fizzbuzz anywhere in your program. The output must be from a machine learned representation that is learned *while running the code*.
2. You must utilize `train.csv` in the training set and check your output against `test.csv`. You cannot use `test.csv` during training.
3. You must get all outputs correct from `test.csv` (but as is case with deep-learning, we'll allow your code to fail this rule no more than 5% of the time).
4. You may use any language and any external module (eg. python/tensorflow) as long they explicitly perform some kind of learning. Reference both the language and the module in the title of your post.
5. This is a popularity contest, so the submission with the most votes after one week wins.

Comment: What are the odds this will work well without an obscene number of iterations? A week doesn't seem like much time to test more than a single method or two.

Comment: @geobits I'm not sure, but I can train a decent random forest model on Netflix predictions or a CNN to recognize basic images in about in hour. I figured the community would enjoy the challenge of a basic programming task in an unconventional manner. Surely fizzbuzz can't be that hard...

Comment: Well, one problem that comes to mind immediately is that you need it to output valid code *at all*. So you're going to need to compile/run/whatever for every slight variation in the code. So then you need to figure out what building blocks you can give it to start with. A list of keywords to try, just random ascii, somewhere in between? That part in particular seems underspecified, but could make or break the odds of it working imo.

Comment: I foresee arguments over where exactly the line falls for "*hard-cod[ing] the rules to Fizzbuzz*".

Comment: Hmmm....if you come up with arbitrary rules of fizzbuzz (like different numbers, different amounts of numbers), that might work  to prevent hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

## Code me music

## Challenge

Write a program that will play music based on input.

## Input

When your program is run it will be given a small song. Each note in the song will have 3 components:

```
[octave][pitch][duration]
```

where `octave` is the [octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation) for the note to be played in, `pitch` is the key of the note (a b c d e f g), and `duration` is the length of the note in milliseconds. For example, `4c1000` would be middle c played for one second. Notes in a song are separated by spaces. Flats and sharps are possible, and they go after the note like this: `5gb1000` (5th octave g flat) for flats and `5g#1000` (5th octave g sharp) for sharps.

## Output

Your program must produce sound based on the input. If one of the notes in the input is `3f500`, your program must play f in the third octave for a half of a second.

## Other notes

- This is code golf, so shortest program in (insert period of time) wins.
- No functions, only full programs.
- The sound can be whatever you please.
- Here are the frequencies of notes in the 4th octave in hertz:

  - 4c - 261.63
  - 4c#/4db - 277.18
  - 4d - 293.66
  - 4d#/4eb - 311.13
  - 4e - 329.63
  - 4f - 349.23
  - 4f#/4gb - 369.99
  - 4g - 392.00
  - 4g#/4ab - 415.30
  - 4a - 440.00
  - 4a#/4bb - 466.16
  - 4b - 493.88
- A list of all frequencies is [here](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/notefreqs.html).

## Sandbox

- Is the challenge objective clear?
- This challenge may be hard for some languages, is that a problem?
- Is this already a challenge?
- Any positive feedback is welcome.

Comment: I think this could be improved by explaining what the frequencies are for the pitches at a given octave, and then explaining how an octave relates to that. That information is necessary to answer in any language which doesn't handle that itself, so I think it warrants being in the post rather than being behind a (potentially stale) link. In addition, you probably need to have some kind of leniency about frequency and duration, machines are not perfect after all.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you for your feedback, updated challenge.

Comment: Yes, [this is already a challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61188/194). (And, curiously, the second sandbox proposal which is a variant on that challenge in just a week).

Answer (score 0):

## Plan a special tournament

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [more tags required]

---

I host a special tournament with any number *n* >= 2 of participants.

Here is a list of plans of tournaments for *n* = 2 to 20:

```
 2: 1) DE-2c-1w
 3: 1) RR-3c-1w
 4: 1) DE-4c-1w
 5: 1) RR-5c-2w 2) DE-2c-1w
 6: 1) RR-6c-3w 2) RR-3c-1w
 7: 1) RR-7c-3w 2) RR-3c-1w
 8: 1) DE-8c-1w
 9: 1) RR-9c-4w 2) DE-4c-1w
10: 1) RR-10c-5w 2) RR-5c-2w 3) DE-2c-1w
11: 1) RR-11c-5w 2) RR-5c-2w 3) DE-2c-1w
12: 1) RR-12c-6w 2) RR-6c-3w 3) RR-3c-1w
13: 1) RR-13c-6w 2) RR-6c-3w 3) RR-3c-1w
14: 1) RR-14c-7w 2) RR-7c-3w 3) RR-3c-1w
15: 1) RR-15c-7w 2) RR-7c-3w 3) RR-3c-1w
16: 1) DE-16c-1w
17: 1) RR-17c-8w 2) DE-8c-1w
18: 1) RR-18c-9w 2) RR-9c-4w 3) DE-4c-1w
19: 1) RR-19c-9w 2) RR-9c-4w 3) DE-4c-1w
20: 1) RR-20c-10w 2) RR-10c-5w 3) RR-5c-2w 4) DE-2c-1w
```

### Explanation of the plan

- The entire tournament enters the first round, which has *c* = *n* participants.
- For each round:

  - If *c* is a [power of 2](http://oeis.org/A000079), then this round will be a double elimination round, with 1 winner. After this round, the tournament ends.
  - Else, this round will be a round robin round, with floor(*c*/2) winners that continue to the next round.

    - If only one winner continues, the tournament ends.
    - Else, let *c* be the number of winners, and start again from "For each round".

### The Challenge

Given *n*, return a plan of the special tournament with *n* participants.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

> TODO: Reword the explanation clearly, write more content.

Comment: How does a round robin with five people work, where you have two winners? Most round robins would have a bye, so you'd end up with three winners continuing on. (same for any odd number)

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a 2d maze (Yes, a whole game)

Nowadays, I am interested in making games. especially mazes. In this golf round of code, You should make a maze game. You can do it with just preset mazes, but, if you make it randomly generate, I will be a-maze-d and will give you bonus points.(Huh. is that a pun?) So, Go on, Why don't you try right now?

DETAILS:

- Input W(Up), A(Left), S(Down), D(Right) until the player gets to the finish.
- Display the maze and the player each input.
- Move the player Up if the input is 'W', Down if 'S', Left if 'A', and Right if 'D'.
- The Character for the wall and the player is undefined. you choose.
- The Character for the wall, the player and the end square should be all different.

MAZE GENERATING:

- You should get the Width and height in the input.
- Not Necessary, but you can use Prim or Kruskal.
- Also you can use the method mentioned in [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25967/maze-generation).

Comment: The spec as is probably has too many ambiguities, e.g. 1) What counts as a "maze"? 2) If I was to golf this question right now, I'd put the exit next to the player and make it so that the only valid move is into the exit. That would save a ton of bytes since I only have to check one input. 3) If random generation is optional, it's almost certain that it won't be done (but if you do make it mandatory, then you would need to specify what random generation means) 4) Do we have to handle invalid input from the user?

Comment: In order for this to fit as a challenge on this site, it needs to have a winning criterion. For example, code-golf (shortest code wins), or fastest-code. You can also use code-challenge if you define a score based on something else, but there must be some way of assigning a score to each solution so they can be put in order and encourage competition.

Comment: I think this could be an interesting challenge, but it needs to be well defined before it will be ready.

Comment: It is code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Light black box: generate mirror processors

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

[ WORK IN PROGRESS - LOTS OF OUTSTANDING QUESTIONS ]

---

## Input

The list of black box output values for all black box input values from 0 to 255 (inclusive), in any reasonable format. Each value is also in the range 0 to 255.

## Output

A text representation of a rectangular grid showing the locations and orientations of mirrors that will generate the appropriate black box output for each black box input.

## Specification

- The input bits arrive from the left of the grid, in the top 8 squares, initially travelling right.
- The output bits depart from the right of the grid, in the top 8 squares, travelling right.
- For both black box input and black box output, the most significant bit is at the top.
- Bits move through the grid horizontally or vertically until they encounter a mirror or the edge of the grid.
- Bits that leave the edge of the grid are lost.
- A bit that would move onto a mirror at the next step instead changes direction by 90 degrees clockwise or anticlockwise according to the mirror type, and takes a step in that direction (a bit never stays on the same square).
- If two or more bits arrive on the same square at the same timestep, all of them annihilate. Two bits can still pass through each other if this does not involve sharing a square (traveling in opposite directions, being adjacent facing towards each other on one step, and adjacent facing away from each other on the next).

Note that because a bit changes direction just before reaching a mirror, there cannot generally be a mirror in an input or output square, as this would prevent the bit entering/leaving by that square. However, a grid taking advantage of input/output that has no requirement for a given bit by placing a mirror that blocks a given input or output square is still valid provided it gives the correct behaviour.

## Example

[ PENDING ]

## Scoring

The score for each input is the area of the resulting grid. The total score will be the sum of the scores for each of the test inputs.

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is this too similar to domino circuits? The photons leave no trail so they can cross over their own and each other's paths arbitrarily many times. Also a given mirror can affect arbitrarily many photons, and each an arbitrary number of times.
- Is this a duplicate of anything else?
- Should the score be just the area of the grid, or also include the time between input and output? The time will have to be the worst case over all inputs, as reading the input before then would give a false result in some cases.
- Should output bits have to arrive at the same time?
- Should the time from input to output be required to be constant over all inputs?
- There cannot be more output bits than input bits. Should test cases reflect this, or should a mechanism be introduced to make all patterns of output possible?
- Should the particles be referred to as "bits", "photons", or something else?
- Currently tie break is first posted. Should the number of mirrors be taken into account as a tie break first?
- Should the grid wrap? I initially thought not, but then I realised there would need to be an extra row above the I/O rows to allow mirrors to redirect onto the top output bit. It might be simpler to keep to having the I/O rows at the very top, and simply put redirecting mirrors in the bottom row. This would make it possible to redirect onto rows 0 and 7 with only 8 rows in total.
- I've chosen mirrors that change the bit's direction just *before* impact, rather than on impact. I liked the fact that this gives an asymmetry - reversing the direction will not reverse the route taken. This introduces the potential for sending a bit back along part of the same path without trivially sending it back to its origin. Is there any reason to stick to the symmetrical case instead?
- The other thought that occurred to me was to have the mirrors change direction too, flipping between the two possibilities at each impact.
- There are `256**256` possible ways to assign a value from 0 to 255 to each of 256 different inputs. This is far too large a space for hardcoding all solutions. However, this doesn't necessarily mean that the worst case grids will be huge. A lower bound on the worst case grid area is `log(256**256,3)`, which is just over 1292 (since there are 3 possible states for each square). The maximal lower bound is likely to be far higher than that, but I have no idea how much higher. I'm likely to settle on a small enough space that code can be expected to deal with any input, but still a large enough space that hardcoding is impossible (I don't want to explicitly rule it out). *(Here `**` indicates exponentiation, as used in python.)*
- Mirrors that split bits, and bits annihilate on collision with each other. This will allow for arbitrary input and output rather than being restricted by the initial number of bits. I'm considering a number of possible approaches:

  1. One mirror type only: always splits a single bit into two bits in the two directions perpendicular to the current direction.
  2. 4 mirror types - each having a dead direction. A bit arriving from that direction is destroyed. A bit arriving from any other direction is split into two bits, one for each remaining direction.
  3. 4 mirror types - each having a dead direction. A bit is only split into two bits if the two perpendicular directions are not dead. Otherwise only one bit is produced, in the available perpendicular direction (or no bits if the bit approaches from the dead direction).
- Can bits be left in the grid that do not terminate? Can a solution specify that the output should be measured at a set time, even if some bits will later reach the output squares altering the result? Should the output only be measured once all activity has ceased - excluding the possibility of using a repeating cycle?

Answer (score 0):

### Point Triangulation

(title suggestions welcome)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

[Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(surveying)) has been used for hundreds of years for land mapping and cartography, until the widespread proliferation of satellite positioning systems. Essentially, if you know two fixed points, *A* and *B*, you can uniquely describe a third point *C* by describing the angles *BAC* and *ABC* (the [angle-side-angle postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#A_side_and_two_adjacent_angles_given_.28ASA.29)). The challenge here will be to solve for *C*.

#### Input

- Two rays (half-lines) of the form `[(a point in x,y coordinates), (a direction in degrees or radians)]` in any convenient format.
- The input angle will be *relative to the Cartesian plane*, i.e., an input of `0` degrees will have the ray parallel to the `x` axis and pointing toward `x=+inf`, and will follow traditional Euclidean convention that the angle increases counter-clockwise (e.g., `90` degrees is "straight up" toward `y=+inf`, `180` is "straight left" toward `x=-inf`, etc.).
- Please specify in your description the input format you're using.

#### Output

- The corresponding third `x,y` coordinate where the rays intersect, thus forming the triangle.
- If the input will *not* form a triangle, you can output an error, crash, output nothing, etc., so long as your code terminates. (*META - is this too harsh? Should the input be guaranteed to form a triangle?*)

#### Examples

```
[(1,0,90), (0,1,0)] -> (1,1)
[(1,0,90), (0,0,45)] -> (1,1)
[(1,0,90), (0,1,180)] -> undefined
```

*additional examples forthcoming*

[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2057/42963)

Comment: I know this is still a WIP, but this challenge has a bit of a red flag for "almost" parallel lines and floating point. When working on it you should come up with a range of inputs that won't cause too many accuracy woes. In addition, I think you need to specify that the geometry should be Euclidean, and that angles follow the convention of being measured counter-clockwise.

Comment: *Intersecting vectors* is not a good phrasing, from your example I suggest *intersecting half-lines (beginning in the given x-y-coordinates and going in the direction of the given angle)* or something like that. At least for me it was unclear from the description that you do mean the half-lines, so I think this is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

### Implement an HTTP Tunnel

I'm bored at work and stuck behind a draconian proxy.

They can take my other ports but they can never take my port 80 freedom!

Help me get all the internets!

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

### requirements

- a single web page that processes GET and POST data and produces output
- if GET `m=start`

  - creates any files you feel are necessary (named pipes, scripts, what-have-you)
  - forks a process which will create a tcp connection
  - connects to host and port based on GET variables `h` and `p`
  - these variables should be cleansed so as not to allow command injection
- if GET `m=in`

  - write the raw POST data to your forked process's tcp connection
- if GET `m=out`

  - get all data available from the forked process's tcp connection and write as response
  - should always return right away (let's say, in less than 1 second)
- if GET `m=stop`

  - kill your forked process
  - clean up any files it has created

### Test data

- http://servername/httptunnel?mode=start&host=ppcg.ga&port=80
- http://servername/httptunnel?mode=in

  - POST data: `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ppcg.ga\r\n\r\n`
- http://servername/httptunnel?mode=out

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: nginx
  Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 02:03:14 GMT
  Content-Length: 0
  Connection: keep-alive
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
  Location: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
  Pragma: no-cache
  ```
- again, to prove the connection is still open, http://servername/httptunnel?mode=in

  - POST data: `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ppcg.ga\r\n\r\n`
- and again, http://servername/httptunnel?mode=out

  - Content returned: same as before
- http://servername/httptunnel?mode=stop

  - system state returned to prior to the first http call

my first instinct was to have this challenge be three separate pieces of code, a client which listens on a port locally and interacts with the web page, the web page itself, and a script which will be forked by the web page. your score would be the sum of all their byte counts. i decided to remove the last as the start process would likely have to create other files so why not have it create the script to run as well, and decided to remove the first option as well to make it nice and even.

is this a feasible challenge? i will add more explanations and test data soon i think. adding my own client would probably be helpful

Comment: HTTP is stateless, so this is a fundamentally broken way of designing a tunnel over it. I can't remember the exact headers, but there are ways in HTTP/1.1 of reusing a single connection for multiple bidirectional data transfers, and that would be the correct way of doing it.

Comment: That's why the "start" mode is going to have to fork another process to handle the actual connection. I have this working with my php script forking a nc process which reads and writes from named pipes. I'll post it later. Sure you could use `Connection: keep-alive` but that connection usually times out pretty quickly, you'd have to implement your own pings to keep it alive, and there's no guarantee how long it would stay alive for.

Answer (score 0):

## Code Golfed Rosetta Code Code Golfer

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (any others? maybe [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf), [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output) and/or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge))

Browsing examples on [the Rosetta Code site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code), I can't help but think that all the code is just so long-winded, inefficient and ...well, readable. Something needs to be done.

#### Challenge

Choose a language, then write a function that takes the example source code, in the *same* language, for specific tasks on Rosetta Code and returns a golfed version of that code.

Winner is the person who can golf the example tasks the most. However, this is a code golf challenge so the length of your own source matters too.

#### Rules

1. Write a function in your chosen language that takes a string as input and returns a string as output (or equivalent - reading/writing to stdio or file, etc is also ok)
2. Input is the source code implementation, in your chosen language, of the following three specific tasks as shown on Rosetta Code (your function runs three times, once for each):

   - [Quicksort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort)
   - [Happy numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Happy_numbers)
   - [Greatest common divisor](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)
3. Output is a code golfed version of the input with identical functionality (again in the same language)
4. If there is more than one implementation of a task for a specific language, you must use the first listed
5. If your chosen language doesn't have an implementation for one of the tasks, then you need to add it yourself (following the Rosetta Code rules - don't go messing up their site just to get a better score here)
6. With the exception of the rule above, you may not, in any way, modify the content or order of examples on Rosetta Code
7. You must leave the logical flow of the algorithm mostly intact (eg. you can't simply replace the [J quick sort code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#J) with `/:~`)

#### Scoring

Score for each individual task is calculated as the output character count as a percentage of the input character count. Implementation score for your own code is simply its character count. Total score for a submission is the sum of the three task scores, plus the implementation score.

*Submission with the lowest score wins.*

So, assuming your function is **100 chars** long and running it against the test tasks gives you the output counts shown, your overall score would be calculated as follows:

```
 Task      | Input char count | Output char count | Score
-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------
 Quicksort |            600   |            400    |  67%
 Happy Nos |            400   |            200    |  50%
 GCD       |            200   |            150    |  75%
--------------------------------------------------+--------
 Implementation score:                            |  100
--------------------------------------------------+--------
 Overall score:                                   |  292
```

---

### Things I'm not sure about...

Before I post this as a challenge, it would be good to get input on a few things:

- Will the "if your language doesn't have an implementation" rule cause problems, or can people be trusted to provide sensible implementations that follow the intent of Rosetta Code and don't simply artificially improve their score on the challenge? Is it better just to deny entries from languages which don't already have implementations?
- With scoring, obviously it's a balancing act, a really terse language will likely get a solid "implementation" score, but should be less able to improve the length of the examples, whereas a verbose language will be the opposite. So, the having too few "tasks" included in the challenge will benefit terse languages, and too many will benefit verbose languages. I want to find a middle ground, so does three tasks seem reasonable?
- Will someone just find an edge case language which has a really easily golf-able Rosetta example, that will make it unbeatable?

Comment: In the given example score, if an empty program echos then it would be better. More worryingly, this seems to allow coding to the test cases. Are the programs required to do something sensible with inputs other than the three test cases?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - re: an empty program, I agree, this absolutely creates a minimum bar to beat, but even the most rudimentary whitespace stripping javascript function: `(s) => {return s.replace(/[\s]{2,}/g,"");};` results in a score of 263, so my example score sheet is more the problem.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Re: coding to the tests, yes this is a bigger problem... The obvious solution is to simply include more tasks, since that would force people to target more generic things, rather than each individual task, but as stated the more you add the more you'll reward verbose languages (I think?)... One possible work around could be just to double things (i.e. have six tasks and make your implementation score, your code length x 2).

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a golf-scoring program! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a space delimited array of integers, find the smallest number. It's that simple.

<sup>[Meta] This may in fact be a duplicate. Please tell me if so.</sup>

Comment: This is basically a dupe of any regular [tag:sorting] question, isn't it? Particularly something like [Sign that word](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55090/31625).

Answer (score 0):

## Distance between two words

You are given an input of two strings consisting entirely of letter characters. The "distance" between two such strings is the number of operations from the following list that it takes in order to transform one word into the other:

1. Adding a letter anywhere
2. Removing a letter anywhere
3. Changing a letter's case

Since your boss wants to avoid wear on the office keyboards as much as possible, you have to write a very short program to determine the distance between words so you can fix the typos.

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67474/levenshtein-distance).

Comment: Almost a duplicate of Leaky Nun's link. The only difference is that the linked challenge allows for straight substitution, whereas here it's two operations (a deletion and an insertion).

Comment: Thanks guys, I had a brief look for dupes but couldn't find anything. If I come up with a good twist I'll edit the OP otherwise I suppose this is dead.

Answer (score 0):

## Cross Validated

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

(This challenge is almost complete, but something doesn't feel quite right)

Continuing the theme of using [site names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/stack-overflowing/) as challenges...

## Your task

Write a program or function that accepts a string, and prints out the location, size, and validity of each cross in the string.

### Definitions

- Valid Cross- A cross where all four spokes of the cross are equal in length. The size of the cross is the number of segments of each cross.

Valid, size 0:

```
+
```

Valid, size 3:

```
   |
   |
   |
---+---
   |
   |
   |
```

- Invalid cross- A cross where one or more spoke is a different length. The size is the number of segments of the **longest** spoke.

Invalid, size 2:

```
 |
 |
-+--
 |
```

Invalid, size 6:

```
+------
```

## Rules

- Each input will have one or more crosses.
- The program should print out the location of the center of each cross. The location is zero-indexed and measured in characters/lines from the top left.
- The size and validity, as defined above, of each cross should be printed out.
- Each test case must pass without printing to STDERR.
- Crosses will not overlap
- Your program can take input via a string (with line breaks), an array of strings (each representing a line), or a 2d array of characters.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest program, in bytes, wins

## Test Cases

```
+ +-
```

(0,0) size 0, valid

(2,0) size 1, invalid

```
   |
   |     |
   |     |
---+---  |
   |     |
   |  ---+
   |
```

(3,3) size 3, valid

(9,5) size 4, invalid

```
(empty test case)
```

(must not crash or print to STDERR)

Answer (score 0):

### This question isn't fair.

I want you to tell me the chances of flipping an coin `n` times and ending up on *tails*.

Naturally this isn't a fair coin. In fact, it isn't even a standard unfair coin, where the chance of flipping *tails* is always `p`. This is a *sticky* coin, where the chance of the coin staying the same is `p`; the coin is fair at other times.

The coin starts off *heads*, so when `n` is 0 or `p` is 1 then the answer is always 0.

Your program or function should be capable of calculating the result to at least six significant digits.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins!

Comment: What does "the coin is fair at other times" mean?

Comment: @LeakyNun Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to ask there. A fair coin is one which is equally likely to produce heads or tails but there is no way of predicting which. This coin isn't always fair; a proportion of the time `p` it repeats the last result.

Comment: You said that the chance of the coin staying the same is `p`. Then, isn't the chance of it being different `1-p`? So, do you mean that `1-p = 50%`?

Comment: I think it means that the chance of the coin staying the same is p + (1-p)/2 and the chance of the coin changing is (1-p)/2.

Comment: @LeakyNun Ah, sorry, the chance of it being _sticky_ is `p`, and of being _fair_ is `¬p`.

Comment: Meaning, that the chance of it being *the same* is `p+(1-p)/2` and the chance of it being *different* is `(1-p)/2`. What a meaningful obfuscation.

Comment: That means that the chance of it not changing is `p + (1-p)/2 = (1+p)/2`, and Sp3000's closed form needs changing to `(1 - p^n)/2`. It's still not exactly an interesting function to golf.

Comment: I can see I should have described the coin of having a chance `q` of flipping, and you needed to calculate the probability of an odd number of flips in `n` trials.

Comment: (Removed my previous comment because I misunderstood and thought the probabilities were `p` and `1-p` for same/change, but ditto Peter's comment)

Answer (score 0):

## "Optimize" a RegEx

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Introduction

Inspired by atrociously large regex's like

```
/[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%&*()_\-+={[}\]|\:;"'<,>.?\/\\~`]+[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%&*()_\-+={[}\]|\:;"'<,>.?\/\\~`]*/g
```

I propose a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge to create a string representing an optimized and sorted regex from an input string of characters expected to be matched.

#### Rules

- only printable ASCII characters with code points 32 - 127 need to be supported:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

The RegEx output string *should*:

- Group 3 or more consecutive code points in the input string together like `begin-end`
- Sort the characters and groups in order of ascending code point
- Escape the literal character `-` to `\-` to differentiate it from a range

The RegEx output string should *not*:

- Escape the characters `!$()*+./=?[\]^{|}`
- Support any RegEx escape sequences like `\w`, `\d` or `\s`

#### Examples

```
Input:
helloworld
Output:
dehlorw

Input:
fedcabXZYVWU
Output:
U-Za-f

Input:
q0`p[|iOf(oc61TSr4dVwQ8m;%YDAPM*a/2j&h~u}
Output:
%&(*/-2468;ADMO-QSTVY[`acdfh-jmo-ruw|-~
```

Just so people can see what the last one's pattern is, here are the ASCII indices:

```
37,38,40,42,47-50,52,54,56,59,65,68,77,79-81,83,84,86,89,91,96,97,99,100,102,104-106,109,111-114,117,119,124-126
```

#### Spoiler Alert

Example implementation in JavaScript ES6:

> ```
> f=s=>[...s] // spread string into array
>   .sort() // sort array by ASCII indices
>   .map(
>     c=>c.charCodeAt() // convert each one to ASCII index
>   ).reduce( // reduce sorted indices
>     (p,c)=>(
>       ~p[0][0]+c? // if last index is not one less than current index
>         p.unshift([c]): // then start new run with this index
>         p[0].unshift(c) // else continue existing run
>       ,p
>     ),
>     [[]] // start reduce with empty run
>   ).map( // map array of runs
>     a=>(
>       (
>         a=a.map( // map each run
>           n=>( // convert index back to ASCII
>             c=String.fromCharCode(n),
>             c=='-'? // if '-'
>               '\-': // then escape it
>               c
>           )
>         ),
>         a.length>2? // if run has more than 2 indices
>           [a[0],'-',a.pop()]: // keep only the begin and end
>           a // else keep whole run
>       ).reverse().join`` // reverse and join run
>     )
>   ).reverse().join`` // reverse and join array
> ```

Comment: This question seems to be about optimising regex character classes, not full regexes. Is that correct?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I suppose you could say that. That's a more wordy title though so I just kept it simple.

Comment: I could understand not requiring any escaping on the grounds that it's a minor detail. I could understand requiring enough escaping to make this actually a useful tool. But it seems really odd to require escaping `-` but not `]`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I decided to escape only the characters that are necessary to determine whether an execution is correct or not. If you have an alternate suggestion, please feel free.

Answer (score 0):

### Exercise your kids

I want you to output the *n*th verse of this kid's exercise song:

> Head, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes,
>   Head, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes
>   And eyes and ears and mouth and nose,
>   Head, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes.

Each verse is the same as the previous except that all occurrences of one word is masked by replacing it with a dash (you can use a two-byte dash of your choice) wherever it appears in the verse. The words are replaced in order however the word "and" is never replaced, therefore the next verse should look like this:

> —, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes,
>   —, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes
>   And eyes and ears and mouth and nose,
>   —, and shoulders, knees and toes, knees and toes.

Also, the last verse should look like this:

> —, and —, — and —, — and —,
>   —, and —, — and —, — and —
>   And — and — and — and —,
>   —, and —, — and —, — and —.

Your answer should specify whether *n* will range from 0 to 8 or 1 to 9.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: Could you show us what the second verse would look like?

Comment: Although it can be deduced from the numbers, I'd recommend changing "one word is masked" to "all occurrences of one word are masked" to be explicit.

Comment: Is this a challenge involving Unicode as the main topic? If not, can we replace `—` (U+2014) by a simple hyphen `-` (U+002D)?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, but you may replace it with a double hyphen, as that's still 2 bytes.

Comment: Actually, it is 3 bytes.

Comment: Something to note is that "and" is the only word in the verse that starts with the letter "a". That means something like `\b(?!a)\w+` will have its first match be the word to replace each time. Also, I don't believe any of the words are prefixes/postfixes of each other, so once you have them you can blindly replace all occurrences of them. This isn't a problem or anything, I just wanted to make sure you knew in case you wanted it to be harder.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100153/34718

Answer (score 0):

### Index sum and strip my matrix

Given a matrix/2d array in your preferable language

**Input:**

- The matrix will always have an odd length
- The matrix will always be perfectly square
- The matrix values can be any integer in your language (positive or negative)

---

**Example:**

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  4  5  6  7  8
3  4  50 6  7  8  9
4  5  6 100 8  9  10
5  6  7  8 -9  10 11
6  7  8  9  10 11 12
7  8 900 10 11 12 0
```

---

**Definitions:**

- The "central number" is defined as the number that has the same amount of numbers to the left,right,up and down

**In this case its middlemost 1000**

- The "outer shell" is the collection of numbers which their x and y index is or 0 or the matrix size

---

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2                 8
3                 9
4                 10
5                 11
6                 12
7  8 900 10 11 12 0
```

### Your task:

Add to the central number the sum of each row and column after multiplying the values in each by their 1-based index

**A single row for example**

```
4  5  6  7  8
```

**for each number**

```
number * index + number * index.....

4*1 + 5*2 + 6*3 + 7*4 + 8*5 => 100
```

---

**example:**

```
 2 -3 -9  4  7  1  5  => 61
-2  0 -2 -7 -7 -7 -4  => -141
 6 -3 -2 -2 -3  2  1  => -10
 8 -8  4  1 -8  2  0  => -20
-5  6  7 -1  8  4  8  => 144
 1  5  7  8  7 -9 -5  => 10
 7  7 -2  2 -7 -8  0  => -60
                         |
78 65 60 45 -15 -89 10   => 154
                     |
                     => -16
```

- For all rows and columns you combine these values..
- Now you sum these too => 154-16 = 138
- You add that number to the "central number" and remove the "outer shell" of the matrix

---

```
 0 -2 -7 -7 -7     => -88
-3 -2 -2 -3  2     => -15
-8  4 1+138 -8  2  => 395
 6  7 -1  8  4     => 69
 5  7  8  7 -9     => 26

19 69 442 30 -26
```

do this untill you end up with a single number

```
-2 -2 -3     => -15
 4  1060 -8  => 2100
 7 -1  8     => 29

27 2115 5
```

- Add 2114+2147 to 1060
- Remove the "outer shell" and get 5321
- Now we have a single number left

**this is the output!**

test cases:

```
-6

-6
```

---

```
-7 -1  8
-4 -6  7
-3 -6  6

2
```

---

```
 6  7 -2  5  1
-2  6 -4 -2  3
-1 -4  0 -2 -7
 0  1  4 -4  8
-8 -6 -5  0  2

-365
```

---

```
 8  3  5  6  6 -7  5
 6  2  4 -2 -1  8  3
 2  1 -5  3  8  2 -3
 3 -1  0  7 -6  7 -5
 0 -8 -4 -9 -4  2 -8
 8 -9 -3  5  7  8  5
 8 -1  4  5  1 -4  8

17611
```

---

```
-9 -7  2  1  1 -2  3 -7 -3  6  7  1  0
-7 -8 -9 -2  7 -2  5  4  7 -7  8 -9  8
-4  4 -1  0  1  5 -3  7  1 -2 -9  4  8
 4  8  1 -1  0  7  4  6 -9  3 -9  3 -9
-6 -8 -4 -8 -9  2  1  1 -8  8  2  6 -4
-8 -5  1  1  2 -9  3  7  2  5 -6 -1  2
-8 -5 -7 -4 -9 -2  5  0  2 -4  2  0 -2
-3 -6 -3  2 -9  8  1 -5  5  0 -4 -1 -9
-9 -9 -8  0 -5 -7  1 -2  1 -4 -1  5  7
-6 -9  4 -2  8  7 -9 -5  3 -1  1  8  4
-6  6 -3 -4  3  5  6  8 -2  5 -1 -7 -9
-1  7 -9  4  6  7  6 -8  5  1  0 -3  0
-3 -2  5 -4  0  0  0 -1  7  4 -9 -4  2

-28473770
```

Comment: yes, that is much better.

hard when English is your 3rd language

Comment: No worries, English is a pretty incomprehensible language no matter who is speaking it ;) Anyway, you identify the central number as "the zero", but the example you gave actually has two zeros. Perhaps change the array or change the wording to the "middlemost zero"?

Comment: For the process to work I think you need the matrix to be square, but I don't see a statement of that anywhere.

Comment: added that

@FryAmTheEggman also changed

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate the Average Squared Error

Given a line *y = mx + b* and a set of *n* points (*x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>*), find the average square error between the given line and each set of points.

[image: Formula]

Your goal is to create a function or program that given the values *m*, *b*, and the set of points (*x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>*), outputs the average square error according to the formula above.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins.
- Builtins that compute this value are not allowed. This includes builtins that compute a result which is a scaled value of this.
- Floating-point inaccuracies will not be counted against you.

### Test Cases

tba

Answer (score 0):

## White Water Rafting

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)[graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

---

This problem is about finding the best path through a bunch of rocks on a 5-column wide river, without crashing your raft. A river looks like this (`*` reprsents a rock):

```
. . . R .
. R . . .
R . . . .
. . R . .
R . . . .
. . . . R
```

Each row will contain exactly 1 rock, no more, no less. Your raft can start on any space without a rock.

You can't maneuver your raft too much, so as you travel down the river, there are only 3 next places you can go (`x` is the next space):

```
. . @ . .
. x x x .
```

If there is a rock in your way, you can't go there. Your raft can't fit through rocks that are diagonally adjacent to each other. You can't beach your raft either. Finally, you can't go anywhere that would result in you crashing your raft.

```
@ . . . .
R x . . .   <- Can't go on rock, can't go oob

R . . . .
. R @ . .
. . R X .   <- Can't go through diagonal rocks

. @ . R .
. R x . .   <- Can go through non-adjacent diagonals,
R . . . .      Can't go to dead end.
```

Because you don't have much space on the raft to write this code, shortest code wins.

### Test cases:

```
Input:

. R . . .
. R . . .
. . . R .
. . . R .
R . . . .

Output:

R x . . .
. R x . .
. x . R .
x . . R .
R x . . .

Input:

R . . . .
R . . . .
R . . . .
R . . . .
R . . . .

Output:

R x . . .
R x . . .
R x . . .
R x . . .
R x . . .

Input:

. R . . .
. R . . .
. R . . .
. R . . .
R . . . .

Output:

. R x . .
. R x . .
. R x . .
. R x . .
R x . . .

Input:

. . . . R
. . . R .
. . R . .
. R . . .
. . R . .

Output:

x . . . R
x . . R .
x . R . .
x R . . .
x . R . .

Input:

. . . . R
. . . R .
. . R . .
. R . . .
R . . . .

Output:

[nothing] or [empty/blank array/matrix]
```

### Notes:

- Input can be in array of indexes, array of truthy/falsey values, or any other input format most comfortable to your language.
- Output should indicate the left-most valid path.
- Output can be in array of indexes, array of truthy/falsey values, or any other input format most comfortable to your language.

  - Output does not have to be in the same format as input.
  - Output nothing/(empty/blank) (array/matrix) if there is no valid path
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.

---

This is my first challenge, so please let me know if I have left anything out or something is unclear.

---

Related problems

- [Follow incomplete directions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73998/42855)

  - Has more obstacles, directions are given
- [How varied is my obstacle course?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65576/42855)

  - About finding paths through an obstacle course
- [Grid-Routing Battle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46886/42855)

  - Similar graph structure

I couldn't find any dupe targets looking through [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid), so I'll look again in [graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) and [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) later.

Comment: I don't have 10 minutes now to sort through all of the dupe targets to work out which one is the most similar, but I guarantee that there is something similar enough that this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

## Regex golf: Match the Thu'um-s

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex)

### Introduction

Skyrim is a game made by Bethesda and came out in 2011. One of the objectives of the game is to collect every 27 shouts (or Thu'um-s). In this challenge, you need to match every shout and nothing else.

### Shouts

This is the list of the available shouts in the game:

```
Raan Mir Tah
Laas Yah Nir
Mid Vur Shaan
Feim Zii Gron
Gol Hah Dov
Od Ah Viing
Hun Kaal Zoor
Lok Vah Koor
Ven Gaar Nos
Zun Haal Viik
Faas Ru Maar
Mul Qah Diiv
Joor Zah Frul
Gaan Lah Haas
Su Grah Dun
Yol Toor Shul
Fo Krah Diin
Liz Slen Nus
Kaan Drem Ov
Krii Lun Aus
Rii Vaaz Zol
Tiid Klo Ul
Strun Bah Qo
Dur Neh Viir
Zul Mey Gut
Fus Ro Dah
Wuld Nah Kest
```

Additionally, every shout can have 3 levels depending on what the player collected so far, each level adds a new word to each shout, so you need to be able t match the separate words without the full shout.

The words need to be uppercase. A shout should only be matched, if it is a separate word, for example: Golf shouldn't be matched.

The separate words for the same shout in the order as in the list appear next to each other, then they need to be in the same match.

The input strings will only contain ASCII letters and spaces as word separators.

### Test cases

*The matched text is bold*

Hydrogen Sulphur **Krah** Coal **Gaan Lah Haas**

one two three four **Kaal** six seven **Joor Zah Frul** eleven

red green blue **Gol Hah** orange purple **Qo** violet

Ran Miir Taah **Raan Mir Tah** raan mir tah

Golf **Gol** Middleage **Mid**

### Rules

- The answer should be a .NET type RegEx and should not contain any other langauge.
- This is a code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/72029/8478) What if a word appears in lower case in the input? What if it appears inside another word like `Golf`? If the latter should not be matched please clarify what characters can be in the input and which of those are valid word delimiters. All that said, I don't see anyone coming up with a good way to compress the words within the limit framework of regex.

Comment: @MartinEnder I clarified it a but

Comment: Still doesn't say what characters can appear in the input and what characters count as word separators (I'm assuming only letters and spaces, and spaces are separators, but if that's your intention you should say so explicitly, and if not, you should add further test cases). Looks good otherwise. To prevent confusion you might want to say explicitly that people should submit *only a regex* and which flavours are allowed (and whether flavours like Perl are allowed to make use of their eval features to execute code in the hosting language).

Comment: If only one language is allowed this would limit the participation in your question. I don't understand why it should be only one language.

Comment: @george  I don't think you know what regex-golf is

Comment: @Bálint Whoops I didn't see your title, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

## Cypher-o-mania!

The year is 19XX.

You are a spy of some distant country, and your job is to send messages across the globe.

Unfortunately, because, frankly, you suck at being a spy, you need a way to obfuscate your information, so that when the opposition catches you (which they will), they won't know what the heck is written.

How are you going to do this?

Your task is, using two inputs (the first input the encoding "cypher" and the second the message), encode the message.

This is how the encoding works:

- The message only consists of the lowercase letters and the numerals.
- Because there are 36 different characters in total, we will convert each individual letter of the message to "base 9" (`a = 00, b = 01, c = 02... 8 = 37, 9 = 38`). This will be called the FSO, or First-Stage Obfuscation.

  - For example, the message `hello1` would then be translated to `07 04 12 12 15 28`.
- Each individual "bit" of the FSO is then stripped of its first part. This will be known as the SSO, or Second-Stage Obfuscation.

  - The example `07 04 12 12 15 28` is then translated to `7 4 2 2 5 8`.
- This is where the encoder comes in handy! The encoder will consist of a string of numbers 0 to 3 (e.g. `1212003`).
- You then add to the start of each digit of the encoder to the corresponding digit of the SSO. This is now the TSO, or Third-Stage Obfuscation.

  - The example `7 4 2 2 5 8` with the encoder `1212003` is then converted to `17 24 12 22 05 08`.
  - With a shorter encoder (say `121`), this step will "wrap around", so `7 4 2 2 5 8` with the encoder `121` will end up with `17 24 12 12 25 18`.
- We then change the TSO back into readable characters, using the same "base 9" method.

  - The two examples `17 24 12 22 05 08` and `17 24 12 12 25 18` will be converted to `QWLUEI` and `QWLLXR` respectively.

So, in summary:

Encoder: `121`

Message: `hello1`

`hello1 => 07 04 12 12 15 28 => 7 4 2 2 5 8 => 17 24 12 12 25 18 => QWLLXR`

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

## META

- This is really confusing, and I don't really know how to phrase the "how the encoding works" bit better. Can anyone help me phrase this better? I can offer clarification on certain things if needed.

Comment: This is basically a mildly astandard and irreversible Vigenère cipher, so it's virtually a dupe of [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/678/194). (I would also say that it violates one of the key criteria for being a good question, which is to have a motivation. The backstory IMO isn't a motivation because it doesn't explain why anyone would want to implement or use what's really a supremely bad hash function).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, IK. I need a lot of things to fix with this question (I was extremely tired at the time, couldn't think of a nice backstory). Also, a few things about the dupe: ONE, it's 5 years ago, so there's bound to be some new answers out there (if it's even a dupe in the first place), and TWO, how is it a dupe?

Comment: It's the difference between `for (i=0 to n-1) s[i] = handleWrapping(s[i] + k[i % klen])` and `for (i=0 to n-1) s[i] = handleWrapping(s[i] % 9 + k[i % klen] * 9)`. As far as I'm concerned that's a very minor transformation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, I kinda understand now. Still some questions, though. ONE: What language is that? TWO: Is there any way I could improve on my explaining?

Comment: 1. It's pseudocode, because I didn't want to faff around working out what escaping a less-than sign needs in comments. 2. I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I would ditch this idea completely and try to find something more original. See e.g. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1475/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, I can see those, but most of those ideas have been taken already, and I kinda want to move away from numbers for a bit and play around a bit with strings and whatnot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Find all the Vampire numbers

Shamelessly stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/q/17352108

A "Vampire" number is defined as the product of two numbers of equal length (known as the "fangs") that uses the same digits as the two numbers being multiplied. Examples:

```
21 * 60 = 1260
15 * 93 = 1395
30 * 51 = 1530
```

Your task is to find all the Vampire numbers whose fangs have `n` digits.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: What about double fangs, triple fangs etc?

Comment: @DerpfacePython Double fangs? But I suppose I could generalise it to `m` fangs of `n` digits if there's enough support (and if there are actually solutions!)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125/31625)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman My bad for not searching first. I might as well delete this.

Comment: I think all you have to do is add the double/triple fang thing and it probably is different enough? Not sure, but there is probably a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

## Forecast Romantic Dates

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

[Sort of inspired by this.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83696/31625)

A Romantic date is a date that, when the year, month and day are converted to [Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) the individual values contain no more than two symbols. For example, in `YY-MM-DD` format: the Romantic date `20-04-15` would become `XX-IV-XV`.

For the purpose of this challenge, years will only be tracked by the two least significant digits of the year, as otherwise the last Romantic date was in the 15th century. In addition, they wouldn't add much to the challenge as the omissions of the leap year every 400 years is irrelevant, as February the 29th is not a Romantic date.

### Romantic dates

For your convenience, here is a list of all of the two digit numbers that can be represented with two or fewer symbols in Roman numerals:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 20, 40, 50, 51, 55, 60]
```

These were determined using the "standard method" that negative groups would only be used with the symbols that are powers of ten and only on the values that are five or ten times that symbol's value. So `I` only combines with `V` and `X` for example.

Dates which include only numbers from this list are Romantic dates. For the purpose of this challenge, assume an ideal Western calendar: no dates are ever skipped or repeated, 12 months per year, and more than 20 days per month. Assume there is no year, month or day zero (i.e. year 99 loops to 1 not to 0).

### Task

Given a date as input, output that date if it is Romantic, or output the next Romantic date.

### Input and Output

You may accept input in any consistent ordering of year, month and day with any consistent separator. You may specify if the input should have the numbers padded to be two digits. If the numbers are padded, you may choose to have no separator. Your output must have the same form as your input.

### Test Cases

The following test cases are all in the format `YY MM DD`, with no padding.

```
1 1 1 => 1 1 1
20 4 3 => 20 4 4
15 7 1 => 15 9 1
51 9 7 => 51 9 9
70 9 7 => 1 1 1
20 6 24 => 20 9 1
47 12 1 => 50 1 1
60 11 24 => 1 1 1
```

[Here](https://repl.it/C5mj/1) is the script that I used to generate these.

### Sandbox

Did I miss any Romantic numbers? I just did that by hand.

Allow unary? I'm unsure about this because it sort of violates the reasoning behind Romantic dates for the values to have >2 symbols...

Should I explain more about parts of dates that are not useful? For example, the length of the months is entirely irrelevant as the later days are all skipped. My concern is that the current one feels clunky already

Should I allow both outputting the input if the date is already Romantic or the strictly next Romantic date (as long as it is consistent)? There doesn't seem to be much different, but I don't know if that'd be too broad? Personally leading towards allowing it.

I'm also somewhat tempted to make use of the silly title a bit more, but I'm not sure if that'd be going overboard.

Too boring / compression based? I've particularly been trying to think of a way for fewer results to wrap back around to 1.

Comment: That rule should be spelt out explicitly in the question, because although some people insist on it it's a modern innovation. There are actual Roman inscriptions which do use e.g. IC.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, I originally left out the reasoning because I thought it might clutter up the spec, but I realise now I just left that comment undeleted to prevent people from asking the same question. I don't have time right now but I'll edit it in once I get a chance. Also, I figured it was better with this rule because I thought say VL was rather unintuitive, does that make sense or should I be more laissez-faire about it?

Answer (score 0):

### Title TBD - Generate Emoticons :)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogov-complexity)

Your task is to create a program that generates the most emoticons using the least amount of code.

#### Rules

- The only valid emoticons are listed on Wikipedia, under the heading
  Western/horizontal emoticons: [List of emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_emoticons&oldid=722951221) page (version
  722951221)
- The output can be any format, as long as a delimiter exists between
  emoticons.

#### Scoring

- Scores will reflect the **character** (not byte) count.
- For every emoticon after 10 that is output by your program, subtract
  `1` from your score. Emoticons over 20, subtract `2`, over 30
  subtract `3`, and so on.

#### Sandbox

Is the scoring fair/reasonable?
Should I edit down the list/create a new list of acceptable emoticons?

Answer (score 0):

## Don't even think about non-42-related numbers!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci)

---

### Introduction and Credit

We all love our [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) which, of course is 42. So let's take this unworthy Fibonacci-Sequence thingy and adapt it to be worthy of 42!

### Specification

#### Input

The input will be a positive integer.

#### Output

The output will be either true or false.

#### What to do?

Your task is to implement the predicate that the number under consideration is an element of the generalized Fibonacci-Sequence given by:

```
a_1 = 14
a_2 = 42
a_n = 41 * a_{n-1} + 43 * a_{n-2}
```

Where 42 is the ultimate answer, 41 and 43 are the primes next to it and 14 is the [preceding catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

#### Potential corner cases

The number will always be greater than zero.
Your program must pass all (32-bit) test vectors below.

#### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

### Test Vectors

```
14 -> true
42 -> true
2324 -> true
4080622 -> true
97090 -> true
171480372 -> true
7 -> false
1 -> false
41 -> false
43 -> false
```

Comment: `a_3` is already outside the range of 8-bit unsigned integers, `a_6` is outside the range of 32-bit signed integers, and `a_11` is outside the range of 64-bit signed integers. It would be worth addressing this issue and at least ensuring that languages which are inherently 8-bit can't just special-case the two values which they can handle.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm unsure how to formulate this without disqualifying legitimate approaches. Would saying "your program must pass all test vectors" (with 32-bit test vectors) also be considered OK for most people?

Comment: I feel like this is too much two separate challenges: one to test for membership in the sequence, and the other to takeWhile on a condition. I also suspect the sequence has a direct arithmetic membership test like the one where `n` is a Fibonacci number exactly if either `5*n*n+4` or `5*n*n-4` is a square.

Comment: What is `takewhile`?

Comment: @xnor, I originally only wanted to do the takeWhile, but needed a (mediumly) complex, interesting predicate, so I came up with this one. Of course I'm open to suggestion for more suitable _interesting_ predicates.

Comment: @DerpfacePython, the higher-order functionality described in the second paragraph of "what to do?" is also called `takewhile`, I've clarified this though.

Comment: @SEJPM I think the other way -- to do a challenge about takeWhile, make the predicate as simple possible. Beware [chameleon challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260) and [needless fluff](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9384/20260). One clean condition would be integers being positive.

Answer (score 0):

## Stacks and Stacks and Stacks...

Write a program that, with the input as `n`, finds the first `n`-gonal and `n`-gonal pyramid number that is NOT 1.

`n` is guaranteed to be larger than or equal to 3.

Examples:

- `n = 3`: `10`
- `n = 4`: `4900`
- `n = 2`: The output can be nothing, `False`, or anything that you want, just as long as it can be distinguished from an actual output.

This is `code-golf`, so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Bonus:

- If your code output both the name of the `n`-gon and the number: You get a big fat **-50%** off of your byte count (see below for examples).

  - `n = 4`: `Square 4900`
  - `n = 3`: `Triangle 10`
  - `n = 5`: `Pentagon ???` (the `???` is a placeholder because I have no idea what the number is)

#### Meta:

- Is the bonus a good idea?

Comment: I don't think the bonus is a good idea because 1) the name compression takes away from the original challenge and likely isn't worth it and 2) you haven't defined the naming scheme (e.g. `12-gon` vs `dodecagon`)

Comment: @Sp3000 Ah, OK. I really want to incorporate the use of strings in the challenge, but if the idea sucks, then I'll scrap it. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Adding strings just makes it feel like squeezing two challenges into one, unfortunately. I'd recommend posting the shape names as a separate challenge, but I see we have [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/polygon-prefixes). As for suggestions, maybe 1) remove the part about `n = 2`, since you already say `n` is guaranteed to be at least 3 and 2) maybe make it explicit that the output should be *both* `n`-gonal and `n`-gonal pyramidal (and maybe explain, say, that 10 is the 4th triangular and 3rd triangular pyramid number)

Comment: Hmm my other problem is - what happens if there's no solution for a given `n`? Note the only reason I'm asking is because the number of solutions for any `n` could be finite, e.g. [A027568](https://oeis.org/A027568). (6 is 946, 8 is 1045, 10 is 175 and 11 is 23725 I believe)

Comment: Yeah, that could be a problem... maybe a time limit? Or maybe check numbers up to a given range.

Comment: One alternative could be to allow solutions to potentially infinite loop/hit memory or recursion errors in the case of no solution/large solution. Numerical limit to check up to could work too, that'd probably be better than a time limit (since it reduces a dependency)

Comment: @Sp3000 I would probably go with the numerical limit/memory limit thing, whichever comes first. But what about golfing/esoteric languages? There might not necessarily be a memory/numerical bound for those.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth Meta-Golf Golf Battery

[metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

(now that's a name, isn't it?)

### The Challenge

Write a program in a language of your choice that takes an input of code in the same language and outputs a code that does the same thing in Pyth (though not necessarily the shortest code).

### Rules

Given the test battery set below, you should try to find the best way to minimize your score with the following rules:

- You must minimize the source code of the submission.

  - You may not used compressed versions of the input source for each test; the Pyth code must be output procedurally.
  - The code must theoretically do the same conversion for any input code, not necessarily just these test cases.
- You must minimize the input code of each test.

  - If an input is shown to be shortenable by without non-standard libraries of the submitted language, you must change it immediately to the shorter answer. If your answer does not support this change, then you must change your answer to accommodate.
- You may not submit answers written in Pyth.

Scoring is done with the following equation:

```
(source code)*((Pyth src out, test 1)/(input src in, test 1)+(same for test 2)+...)
```

### Objectives of each test

#### Test 1:

Output the string "Hello, world!".

#### Test 2:

Given an integer input, multiply that input by three and output it.

#### Test 3:

Quine. (must be a valid quine in the submitted language and in Pyth)

#### Test 4:

Produce infinite output.

#### Test 5:

Cat program.

Comment: I'm not a Pyth expert, but I strongly suspect that what this asks is impossible in many languages. E.g. I understand that Python's multi-threading support is extremely limited. Even if true impossibility is not an option, answers in many languages won't fit inside the 30000-character limit. E.g. I don't think the *grammar* for Java fits inside the limit, let alone a lexer and parser.

Comment: I agree with Peter, that this seems like unless you use only trivial languages it probably won't be possible to answer. The scoring would also make this confusing: to make sure a solution is correct one would have to not only test 10 programs, you would also have to golf 5 programs. Further, there is a bit of a problem in Pyth's `$` operator, which runs literal Python, which means you should probably ban Python as well. I'm not really sure of how to turn this into a good question, too heavily restricting the type of program seems to be the only way, but it also seems to defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

## Generate a random Vietnamese syllable

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

---

The Vietnamese syllable space is interesting, because it is *huge*.

> TODO: Describe the space and why it is interesting.

Here's how such syllables are made:

```
The onset matches the regex ^([bcdđghklmnprstvx]|qu|[cgkpt]h|ng|tr)$

The vowel is one of the following massive list:

a à a' ã á a.
â â` â' â~ â´ â.
a. ă` ă' ă~ ă´ ă.
e è e' e~ é e.
ê ê` ê' ê~ ê´ ê.
i ì i' ĩ í i. ia iê
o ò o' õ ó o. oa oă oe
ô ô` ô' ô~ ô´ ô.
o' ò' o" õ' ó' o'.
u ù u' ũ ú u. ua uâ uê ui uô uo' uy
u' ù' u" ũ' ú' u'. u'a u'o'
y y` y' y~ ý y. ya yê

The coda matches the regex ^([iouycptmn]|ch|ng|nh)$
```

(thanks Peter Taylor!)

The onset, vowel and coda are concatenated to make the result syllable.

### Objective

The objective is to generate random Vietnamese syllables. Your program has to take no input and as output include *only* the syllable, with an optional trailing new line.

### Clarifications

- Each syllable must be generated with a non zero probability.

> I think it's unclear. Contributions are so much welcome.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by *can be with*. 2. You don't mention randomness anywhere excwpt the clarification. 3. *Object* should probably be *Objective*.

Comment: 1. `c can also be with h` means that h can follow c as the 2nd stage letter in the syllable. 2. Where should I also mention it? 3. Ah k :)

Comment: If I'm reading this correcting then it can be vastly simplified by saying that the onset matches the regex `^([bcdđghklmnprstvx]|qu|[cgkpt]h|ng|tr)$`, the vowel is one of a massive set of options (I don't see any benefit to splitting that into "stage 2" and "stage 3"), and the coda matches the regex `^([iouycptmn]|ch|ng|nh)$`

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the mincut of a graph [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), compute a division of the graph such that the edges stranded between the cut.

[image: hayo mouseover readers; leave a comment if you see this!]

**Red line: a cut**

**Green line: a mincut**

### Input

The first line will contain the number of nodes. The rest of the lines will contain pairs of positive integer IDs separated by spaces showing connectedness between the nodes with those IDs. Here's an example; for a graph where 1 is connected to 2 and 2 is connected to 3:

```
3
1 2
2 3
```

- You may assume that the nodes are numbered consecutively from one to the number of nodes.
- However, you may not assume that the list of pairs of nodes is in any specific order.

### Output

Simply output a comma-separated list of the IDs of the nodes of one of subgraphs created by the cut.

### Additional Rules!

- **You cannot implement brute-force search.** Other than that, feel free to use [Karger's Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) or another algorithm. Remember that Karger's algorithm is likely the easiest to implement.
- Notice: you must run Karger's algorithm at least [this many times](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/715acbd0204487481aa29440a228cb0008d3253a) to ensure a low chance of failure and a low chance of failure

### *Karger's algorithm

For your convenience, I've included a simple description of Karger's algorithm.

1. find two adjacent nodes and merge them into one node (so that all nodes that where connected to the original two nodes are connected to the new node), concatenating the labels
2. repeat step one until there are only two nodes
3. the result is any label of one of the nodes
4. repeat steps 1-3 at least [this many times](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/715acbd0204487481aa29440a228cb0008d3253a) to ensure a low probability of failure, and choose the result that occurs the most often

Comment: 1. Wouldn't it be better to take the graph as an adjacency matrix or list? 2. Your description of the minimum cut is somewhat confusing. 3. Karger's algorithm is probabilistic, which isn't allowed by our defaults (I don't think). Allowing probabilistic algorithms opens up a whole can of worms (for instance I could write a program that just returns a random cut) -- you should probably make it so that the algorithm must return the minimum cut two-thirds of the time or something similar if you want to allow them.

Comment: @quartata 1. it's an adjacency list 2. yeah I need help with that 3. I made sure you had to repeat it `insert some math equation here` amount of times

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the input.

Comment: Generally adjacency lists are done like `[node1, connected_node1, connected_node2, ...]` and not in pairs like you have it; this is more flexible and you don't have to specify the number of nodes (it is just the length of the input list)

Comment: "You cannot implement brute-force search" is too vague. What about a basically brute force search that shortcuts some obviously wrong possibilities? I think what you want is a running time bound.

Comment: 1. The I/O description seems to assume that all answers will be programs taking input on stdin and writing output to stdout, but our defaults are more flexible. In particular, by default we allow answers to be functions which take arrays and return arrays. Comma-separating is also IMO unnecessarily constrained, especially as the input isn't comma-separated.

Comment: 2. "*Feel free to use Karger's algorithm or another algorithm*". There's an implicit licence here to use another non-deterministic algorithm, but although you give an explicit iteration count for Karger's algorithm you don't for e.g. randomised Kruskal's algorithm, which it's based on. 3. Besides which, in general I don't think that questions should tell people which algorithm to use. Specify the task and constraints (e.g. "Randomised algorithms are allowed, but must find the correct answer with probability at least foo. All answers must be polynomial-time").

Comment: 4. But if you're going to include an algorithm description, be careful to get it right. Karger's algorithm is randomised, but in the description given there's no mention of where the random selection occurs or of what uniformity constraints are required to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Food for thought: outputting the value of the min cut instead might lend to more approaches. Also, any rules on min cut/max flow/possibly other optimisation builtins?

Comment: I'm going to add a story to this soon.

Answer (score 0):

## nth number that multiplies k equals its reverse

Tags: [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golfing),[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

It's quite simple, given `n` and `k`, output the `n`th number such that, if the number is multiplied by `k` and its digits reversed, it equals the original number. Both input and output are positive numbers.

---

The challenge originally is from [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego), posted on [my broken challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84584/n-numbers-that-its-quadruple-equals-its-reverse#comment207232_84584).
Firstly, I used 4 instead of `k`, but based on my tests, only 1 and 4 values gives output, so I decided to put 4 instead of k, finally I put `k` back. But the challenge would be ruin with that putting `"9"*(n-1)` between 2178, so no loopholes will be permitted.

I just posted here for further discussions, suggestions and improvements.

Comment: Those numbers are positive right?

Comment: Please add some examples of expected outputs.

Comment: Also you might want to prevent people from hardcoding `2178` in any fashion in their code so that they have to compute the numbers, because it seems they all are of the form `21X...X78` where `X...X` is a series of nines (except for the first one, which is 0).

Comment: According to the community advises, I'm not allowed to prevent people use methods those work perfectly.

Comment: Let's wait to see what others think. I personally don't think it's very interesting if people are allowed to hardcode the "format" of those numbers.

Comment: Me neither, I think the challenge isn't interesting at all.

Comment: I think there's no good way to prevent hardcoding. Maybe making "4" were an input parameter as well would make solutions actually search for an answer?

Comment: @xnor You mean make 4 as `k` input?

Comment: @Ehsaan Yes, exactly.

Comment: 9 works too: 1089 * 9 = 9801.

Answer (score 0):

## Let's play some Briscola

[Briscola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briscola) is an Italian game, played with a deck of 40 cards, divided in 4 suits - coins (denari - D), swords (spade - S), cups (coppe - C) and clubs (bastoni - B).

The values on the cards range numerically from one through seven, plus 3 special cards - knave (11), knight (12) and king (13).

### Gameplay:

After the deck is shuffled, each player is dealt three cards.
The next card is placed face up on the playing surface, and the remaining deck is placed face down.
This card is the Briscola, and represents the trump suit for the game.

First player starts by playing one card face up on the playing surface.
Each player subsequently plays a card in turn, until all players have played one card.

The winner of that hand is determined as follows:
If any briscola (trump) has been played, the player who played the highest valued trump wins, else the player who played the highest card of the lead suit (suit of the first card played) wins.

### Ranking

Briscola has a special type of ranking:

```
1   ace
3   three
13  king
12  knight
11  knave
7
6
5
4
2
```

### Rules:

Standard loopholes apply.

#### Input:

As an input, you must accept 5 values (cards), in a reasonable format, for example:

```
briscola (trump card), 1. card, 2. card, 3. card, 4.card
```

#### Output:

You must output the winning card

#### Example input and output:

```
4S 7D 12B 13B 2S -> 2S
5D 1D 5D 12S 3C -> 1D
3B 2C 4S 5S 7D -> 2C
12D 3S 11B 1B 7S -> 3S
```

Comment: As mentioned in chat, I think this is probably a duplicate of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49033/31625). Just adding so other people don't have to go looking.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that can determine the median value of a read-only (static, const, immutable) sequence of unsorted numbers (array, list, stream) but minimises storage, without completely sacrificing speed.

The basic bracket is that if we copied all the values into a sorted list and then picked the middle one (or average of the middle pair), it would require storage of the whole sequence, so the storage would be 'n', and the performance would be O(n log n).

The score is the total cost of finding the median of 1 bn values, divided by 1 bn, at a cost of 8 per value stored, 1 per comparison or numerical operation and 1 per read, for the worst case. Thus if our insertion sort costs exactly `n*log2(n)`, the for 1 bn values the total score is 1 for the read, 29.8 for the sort + 8 for the storage, for a total of 37.8.

If instead we skimmed the whole range to get the average (costing 1 for the read and 1 for the summation), we could then only store some portion of the range to sort; but then we would need a second pass to be sure that there were an equal number of values above and below this median (at the cost of another 2).

Lowest score wins, low-level languages (C/C++/D) only so that we can count the actual operations.

Comment: 1. It's not clear to me what counts as a "*value stored*" or a "*read*", and I think there are probably gray areas with "*comparison or numerical operation*" too. (E.g. in C is `if (foo)` a comparison?) 2. "*The score is the total cost ... for the worst case.*" For any non-trivial algorithm, the full calculation of this score risks being longer than the code. There's a reason that complexity theorists deal with Landau notation rather than exact operation counts.

Answer (score 0):

## Reinventing the Modularization Wheel

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In a language of your choice, implement a function or language construct that imports another file of the same language and executes it, making exported values from that file available to the calling file. If one already exists, you may not use it in your implementation.

For example, in Node, you would have to implement `require()` without using `require()`, even indirectly. In C, you would implement a function or construct equivalent to `#include` without using `#include` in the implementation. In Python, you would implement `import`. In client-side JavaScript, I suppose the closest equivalent would be `<script src="..."></script>`. So JavaScript implementations would be restricted to AJAX calls only, since `<script>` tags would not be allowed in the implementation.

This is not to say that you aren't allowed to use the built-in import *at all*, but only use them in the implementation. The intention here is to reinvent the wheel.

### Requirements

- Do not include the built-in modularization in any way in your import implementation.
- Standard libraries only.
- Byte-count includes the implementation itself, and any special changes that need to exist on the file being imported, if any.
- The function or construct accepts a relative file path. As long as this is satisfied, you may extend the functionality of your modularization to have global imports, or even remote imports (like using a URL as input).
- The imported file must have a construct for denoting values that must be exported. Only these values should be directly accessible from the calling file.
- Using the built-in export function or construct of your language is acceptable, and if it is a built-in, it does not need to be included in your byte-count.
- If your language does not have modularization, then implementing a mechanic for exporting should be included in your byte-count.
- Document the usage of your function or construct.

#### This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Perhaps just restrict this to languages which support modularization to avoid loopholes

Comment: @Downgoat if people wanted to use a built-in for reading a plaintext file, and then use an `eval()`-like built-in to execute it in a way that exposes only denoted values (however you define that), I think it would be acceptable. What sort of loopholes do you foresee?

Answer (score 0):

## Print a Pilcrow Scarecrow

Print the following ascii scarecrow using the [pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) character `¶`

```
    ¶¶¶
   ¶¶¶¶¶
    ¶¶¶
    ¶¶¶  ¶
 ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
    ¶¶¶
    ¶¶¶
   ¶ ¶ ¶
  ¶¶ ¶ ¶¶
     ¶
     ¶
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
```

- Padding must be with   (space) and built with `¶`
- Trailing padding is okay
- Print to stdout
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Answer (score 0):

## It's time to unify!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [logic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

### Introduction

Wouldn't it be awesome if they whole world would be united and there would be no conflicts and disputes? Now while you can't unify nations, you certainly can unify expressions to resolve their unknown relation and conflicts.
Your mission is simple: Unify the world (of expressions)!
And of course, because you're lazy you want to do this with the least effort (read: code-length) possible.

### Specification

#### Input

Your input will be a [*unification problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)). **You can format it however you want and need, as long as you don't encode additional information to what is given in the standard / example format.** Encoding the number of arguments per function into the input is allowed but not mandatory, you can also just derive this from the input.

Example format:
Your first input will be list of function symbols, which is represented as a list of pairs of strings and non-negative integers.
Your second input will be a list of equalities (you may represent each as a string), which represent the unification problem. They will be represented as a list of strings as well. Anything which is not a parenthesis or an equality sign can be considered a variable. If the number of arguments is 0, parenthesis are omitted.

Example input:
`[("f",1),("g",2),("h",3),("a",0)], [x=f((g(a,y)),y=h(g(f(a),z),f(z),a)]`

#### Output

The output is either some falsy value or something representing a list of equalities. It is allowed to use the empty list to indicate a falsy value.

#### What to do?

You need to unify the inputs you got. In the end there must only be variables on the left side of the equality-signs if the you didn't encounter an error. If you did you need to report it (-> false or empty list).

To do the unification, you can - but don't have to - use [Martelli and Montanari's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#A_unification_algorithm), which goes as follows:

```
E is always the (complete) set of equalities except the current one
x,y,z are variables, f,g,h are functions, t1,t2, ...,tn,s1,...,sn are arbitrary terms (compositions of functions and variables)
{x=x} E => E, e.g. if you encounter two equivalent variables, discard
{f(t1,...,tn)=f(s1,...,sn)} E => {t1=s1,t2=s2,...,tn=sn} E, e.g. if you encounter the same function on both sides, unify the arguments along with your rest
{f(t1,...,tn}=g(s1,...,sn)} E => Error, if the symbols are different, you can't succeed
{x=f(t1,...,tn)} E => {x=f(t1,...,tn)} E[x -> f(t1,...,tn)], e.g. if you see a variable equals a term, replace the variable with this term in all other expressions
{x=f(t1,...,tn)} E => Error, e.g. if any of the t1,..,tn contain x at some point
{f(t1,...,tn)=x} E => {x=f(t1,...,tn)} E, e.g. if you see a variable "naked" on the right side, swap the sides
```

Two step-by-step examples are provided below additionally to the test cases.

#### Corner Cases

You can get an empty list of function symbols, this means you have exclusively variables in the second input.
The input list of equalities will never be empty, your code does not need to handle this case.

#### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

### Test-cases

```
All these test cases use the functions [("a",0),("b",0),("f",1),("g",1),("h",2)]

[x=b] -> [x=b]
[a=x] -> [x=a]
[a=b] -> []
[y=f(x)] -> [y=f(x)] 
[x=f(x)] -> []
[f(x)=f(y)] -> [x=y] 
[f(x)=g(y)] -> []
[h(x,y)=h(a,b)] -> [x=a,y=b] 
[x=f(z),y=f(a),x=y] -> [x=f(a),y=f(a),z=a]
[h(x,f(y))=z,z=h(f(y),v)] -> [x=f(y),v=f(y),z=h(f(y),f(y))]
```

#### Step-By-Step Example

```
Example 1: Test Case 9
[x=f(z),y=f(a),x=y] => (replace x in third equation with first x)
[x=f(z),y=f(a),f(z)=y] => (replace y in third equation)
[x=f(z),y=f(a),f(z)=f(a)] => (remove f's in third equation)
[x=f(z),y=f(a),z=a] => (replace the z in the first expression)
[x=f(a),y=f(a),z=a]

Example 2:
Let [("f",2),("g",2),("a",0),("b",0)] be your functions
[f(g(a,x),g(y,b)=f(x,g(v,w)),f(x,g(v,w))=f(g(x,a),g(v,b))] => (remove f in second equation)
[f(g(a,x),g(y,b)=f(x,g(v,w)),x=g(x,a),g(v,w)=g(v,b))] => (function symbol missmatch in equation 2)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## create a golfed down regexp that matches all substrings

inspired by [Determine the "Luck" of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84841/determine-the-luck-of-a-string) where I found a way to golf almost 30 bytes at once
(with a falling trick for that challenge, but I still like the idea).

The word "lucky" contains 15 different substrings:

- lucky
- luck, ucky
- luc, uck, cky
- lu, uc, ck, ky
- l, u, c, k, y

**Challenge**
Create a program or function that, for a given string `s`, creates the shortest possible regexp using basic PCRE syntax that matches and returns all substrings of `s` and nothing else.

- code needs not to be case sensible
- basic syntax means: alternatives, quantifiers, grouping and custom character classes (e.g. `[abc]`)
- other features (assertions, backreferences, recursion etc.) may be used, but are not required to qualify
- the result may include delimiters and modifiers

The result for `lucky` would be `l?ucky?|l?uc?|c?ky?|l|c|y`.

---

- is the description sufficient?
- the challenge not too easy, not too hard?
- any other hints you might have?
- I will add test cases that expose possible bugs (like `silly` and `digdug`)
- not sure yet if I will go for shortest code yet

Answer (score 0):

## Golf your way from (inc|dec)rements to the basic math operations

Write five different functions or programs that do addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo with integers **by only using increments, decrements, loops/recursion and comparisons**.

- Assume division & modulo will never receive 0 or negative integers as the divisor/modulus.
- Modulo's result has the sign of its dividend.
- Division truncates its quotient, e.g `divide(11, 4)` returns 2 and `divide(-5, 3)` returns -1.
- Programs must print the result to STDOUT. Functions must return the result.
- Your five functions/programs may invoke each other.
- All functions/programs must support 32-bit **signed** integers, i.e everything between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (inclusive). Overflow is allowed, i.e it's OK if `add(2147483647, 1)` returns -2147483648.
- Explicitly adding/subtracting 1 to/from numbers is allowed, in case you use a programming language that doesn't have built-ins for incrementing and decrementing.
- [Shortest program wins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) as long as it doesn't exploit [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?noredirect=1&lq=1)!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

I seriously have no idea how to make test cases for this.

Comment: Why not *one* function that returns all of those?  You should also specify what you mean by *divisions* and *modulo* as they differ slightly from language to language. (E.g. what is `-2 mod 5`? and what is `-1/2`?) And *only doing increments/decrements, loops/recursion and compraisions* is also quite vague.

Comment: I don't think test cases would really be necessary since it's just basic arithmetic. You can easily tell if your output is correct or not. Also, I'm assuming that division will truncate the quotient since there isn't really any way to do decimals in this fashion, but that should probably be specified.

Comment: I already did this because I was bored...

Answer (score 0):

## Write a Gopher Interpreter

This code golf challenge will task you with writing an interpreter for an esolang I created a while back called Gopher, Details on the language can be found **[Here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Gopher)**

## Pass Conditions

This challenge requires you to create an Interpreter (Or you could go a step ahead and create a Compile/Transpiler) however for the code to pass as correct it must meet the following criteria

- Take in a single input being the Gopher Code
- Output the result of the Interpreted code
- Invalid code does not need to be handled, however you may do so if you wish
- As this is code-golf the smallest byte size wins

## Example Input and Output

Input:

```
&++<'×<&÷+<^-<<×-<#!+<$@-<&@<×-<@++<@<.!<=
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks for using the Sandbox! Anyway, you should add the relevant information on Gopher to the body of this post, as if your github account/repo dies or is changed people still need to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look, it seems there isn't a challenge for "Given any date, output the day of the week". Is that a challenge worth having?

Something like

"Given an input date, in the form dd/mm/yyyy, output the day of the week"

Shortest code wins

What do we think? perhaps this already exists and I didn't find it.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2878/42963)

Comment: Glad I checked!

Answer (score 0):

### ASCII to Unicode equation beautifier

You may well be used to typing equations in ASCII, but with the advent of Unicode we can spruce them up a bit. We can fix

- Powers (numeric superscripts only)
- Numeric subscripts
- Mathematical signs (-, *, / ^ → -, ×, ÷, ↑)

Examples:

```
x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)  →  x³ − 1 = (x − 1)(x² + x + 1)
g_0 = 3^^3^^3 -= 3^(3^3)        →  g₀ = 3↑↑3↑↑3 = 3↑(3³)
800*600                         →  800×600
1/x                             →  1÷x
```

You may assume that all digits directly after a ^ or _ are meant to be super/subscripts (and the ^ or _ to be removed) and that all the mathematical signs are to be replaced wherever they appear.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: This seems to be two questions crammed into one. The first one is the superscript and subscript transformation, which is mildly interesting; and the second one is the straight substitution of various characters for others, which is completely boring apart from the ambiguity it introduces in the interpretation of `^`. I suggest ditching the substitution of minus, times, and divide symbols and giving explicit lists (with copyable characters and Unicode code points in decimal and hex) of the superscript, subscript, and up-arrow characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Autotune a chord

[Auto-Tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune) is a [pitch correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_correction) program which alters the pitch without changing the length. It can be used to fix off-pitch chords in music, which is good because I have an out of tune piano. The goal of this challenge is given some input waveform which contains a single chord played on my piano, tune each note to the [nearest equally tempered note found on a standard piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies) (see Input for more details).

## Input

The input is something which looks like a time-domain audio sample input containing a single chord being played. All data is sampled at 192kHz, with 16-bit PCM (little endian integer), mono channel. The input may come from any source desired (file io, stdio, function parameter, etc.).

## Output

The output of your code should be something which looks like a time-domain audio sample containing the tuned chord. It does not need to have the same sample rate or datapoint format as the input, but must be the same length in real time as the original sample (or as close as possible). The output may be to any source desired (file io, stdio, function parameter, etc.).

## Examples

See [this github repo](https://github.com/helloworld922/chords_examples) for various inputs and outputs. The provided examples have inputs/outputs in an uncompressed wav file. Feel free to re-encode/gut the data for your inputs.

## Scoring

This is code golf; shortest code wins. Standard loopholes apply. You may use any libraries/builtins so long as they were not designed specifically for performing pitch correction.

**Main concern:** This challenge seems potentially too difficult, so one alternative I've been considering is changing the piano samples into sine waves at the fundamental frequencies (avoids issues with amplitude decay/harmonics). An even simpler challenge might be to give inputs in the frequency domain (list of fundamental frequencies), though I'm not sure that would make for an interesting challenge as it seems almost too easy at that point.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

Comment: It seems very difficult to determine what outputs are considered correct.

Comment: yeah, that thought had crossed my mind as well. I've considered measures based on the delta of the FFT of user output/expected output, but I'm not sure this is necessarily a good measure of "in tune".

Comment: I suspect that the biggest technical challenge would be phase. The harmonics of each string in isolation should be in phase, because they all derive from a single hammer strike, but the keys of the chord are probably not all struck at exactly the same time, and there will be resonant driving interactions between them which will complicate the signal. I suggest that you explicitly state that people can ignore this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. Additional tags are [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet), [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) and [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math).

## How fast is your Stack Exchange community?

---

**tl;dr**

Your task is to find how fast a Stack Exchange community reacts. "*How fast*" is here the average of the time elapsed until the first answer or the closing of the question.

**Input**

- the Stack Exchange site's name, e.g. `stackoverflow`, `codegolf`, `codereview` etc.
- optionally the Stack Exchange API URL: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/`

**Requirements**

- Calculate the average time it takes until the first answer or closing of the question.
- Take the *1000 latest questions* into account, e.q. ten API requests with 100 items each.

**Output**

- Output the average time in *minutes and seconds*, like `01:23` or `1:23`.
- Run your program at least against `stackoverflow`, `codegolf` and `code review` and show the results.
- Feel free to add results for your other favorite communities as well.

**Boilerplate**

- You can write a program or a function. If it is an anonymous function, please include an example of how to invoke it.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Leading/trailing whitespaces/newlines are fine.

Comment: How do you count unanswered and unclosed questions? Also, I don't know about the API, but there might be problems with deleted answers. I think you should probably write a reference implementation before posting this.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks a lot – all good points. Didn't think that there might be questions that are unclosed *and* unanswered. Will check the API whether *deleted* even will be send. Good point with the reference implementation – maybe in JavaScript that it can be run as a stack snippet. What do you think in general about the challenge idea? Boring? Interesting? Too complicated?

Comment: It's about doing basically one task, so I don't think it is complicated. I think the results are probably more interesting than the challenge (there are only so many ways to average something and to parse html), but it makes sense and isn't trivial, so I wouldn't say it's boring. Seems fine overall. Also note [tag:internet], [tag:date] and, I suppose, [tag:math].

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks again for your feedback and the tag suggestions. I also think that the results are the interesting part. I wanted to try a popularity contest in the first place because of that. But I couldn't come up with the necessary criteria. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Convert a BMP image to grayscale

The images manipulation is a great way to exercise and increase your skills. In my opinion it's also very interesting.

## What you must do?

The objective of exercise is much easy: convert an image bmp colorful in an image grey.
You can use every language, the question most appreciated will be that don't use library.

Image stock: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/c491/p7aya9cxafvfc91zg.jpg
Image converted:  http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3903/rcigd79pkwd12qczg.jpg?size_id=3

Comment: What is the winning criterion? It is code-golf, popularity-contest, other criterion?

Comment: Also, the `You can use any language` is unnecessary, it's implied here. And you can use `![](<image url>)` to show the images.

Comment: This is very underspecified at present. 1. What weights should be used in the conversion from RGB to greyscale? 2. What bit depths should be supported? 3. Is it required to support all of BMP's features (e.g. ICC colour profiles, CMYK, JPEG, PNG)? If not, what is the minimum feature set which must be supported?

Comment: @Blind To mention someone, you can use `@<username>`, and please add the tags to your post (`[tag:<tag name>]`)

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg , It's a code-golf. @ Peter Taylor , It's equal, you can use that weight you want. 2.see 1st. 3.just support BMP.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer questions 2 or 3.

Comment: Just to let you know, you can only @mention one person per comment, and it won't work with a space between the @ and the name.

Answer (score 0):

## Do I have an emoji?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given an input [string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string) in your language, return [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190/19617) if the input contains an valid [Unicode emoji character](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

### What is an Emoji?

The word emoji comes from the Japanese:

絵 (e ≅ picture) 文 (mo ≅ writing) 字 (ji ≅ character).

Emojis are pictorial symbols used to represent feelings, actions, or objects.

For this challenge, use the [Full Emoji Data](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) list provided by Unicode as a reference to determine which characters are valid Emojis.

Sample test cases:

`""` -> `0`

`""` -> `1`

`"hello"` -> `1`

`"hello"` -> `0`

`"!±≡"` -> `0`

---

Discussion:

This seems trivial, but I noticed we didn't have an emoji detection challenge.  There might be a concern about the encoding of the input string, but reading the linked meta posts about Strings I feel that this challenge can use whatever String format the language used in the answer supports.

The acceptable output for booleans is also up for discussion.  Do we have a meta post on what output formats are acceptable for booleans?

Comment: One question: What *exactly* is an emoji? I think it should be specified in the challenge.

Comment: See http://meta.ppcg.lol/q/2190, just say truthy/falsey.

Comment: @zyabin101 can I use [Unicode's emoji list](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) as a list of valid emoji characters for this challenge?

Comment: Up to you. [filler text]

Comment: I've attempted to clarify what an emoji is, at least for this challenge.  Hopefully this will make this question more clear and a better fit for the site.

Comment: A source which gives actual ranges would be more convenient for people writing answers, although http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/3.0//emoji-data.txt isn't entirely consistent with the other lists.

Answer (score 0):

### Trim trailing spaces in less than O(n²) time

Since `s/\s+$//` [runs in O(n²) time](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016), Stack Overflow needs to replace it with something faster. Please write a code snippet for them. Your score will be the number of bytes in your submission, multiplied by the time taken to process a string of 1000 non-spaces with 1,000,000 leading and trailing spaces, divided by 1000 times the time taken to process a string of 1-non space with 1,000 leading and trailing spaces. (In other words, if your code runs in O(n) time then this should cancel out.)

Comment: The fancy scoring seems like it might be confusing/hard to implement. Why not just restrict the complexity to be less than **O(n²)** like you suggest in the title?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's fairly easily fixed with `(?<!\s)\s+$` or using RTL matching in .NET/Retina. (In fact, the latter would probably be a good candidate for winning the challenge even if actual runtime is taken into account.)

Comment: @MartinEnder That is what I had in mind ;) Is there a reason that would be bad? I think that is likely around the best performance you can get, being linear w.r.t. the number of spaces at the end of the string?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman well it just means there's likely a very simple solution that might win the challenge.

Comment: The scoring mechanism is not going to work well because the times will be so small that there will be more noise in the measurement than signal. Especially for the smaller test case, where the string will fit in L1 cache.

Comment: The scoring can be exploited by intentionally doing badly on smaller cases.

Answer (score 0):

Given an ordinal A and a nonnegative integer B, compute f_A(B)

A will be expressed in Cantor Normal Form. A number is in Cantor Normal Form if it is 1, or if it is either of the form a+b or w^a, where a and b are in Cantor Normal Form, and w is the ordinal omega.

f_A(B) is the fast-growing hierarchy, specifically, the Wainer Hierarchy.
f_0(n)=n+1.
f_(a+1)(n)= n iterations of f_a to n.
f_a(n)=f_an if a is a limit ordinal.
a[n] is the nth member of the fundamental sequence for a.

Comment: You'll definitely need to add the definitions of these, as most people won't have any idea how to answer. You can use one of various online TeX -> image services and add those to your post. Sadly we don't have MathJax activated because it borked a bunch of other features. I'd also heavily recommend adding some test cases.

Comment: Test cases are impossible to add. But thanks for formatting advice!

Answer (score 0):

### Reverse stdin to stdout, Unicode aware and by grapheme clusters

It's 2016. High time that we were Unicode-aware, don't you think?

Given a UTF-8 string on stdin, reverse it by extended grapheme clusters (as defined by the Unicode consortium; this can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries), for instance) and place it on stdout. This is seemingly a trivial challenge, but surprisingly difficult in many languages.

You may not use an explicit end-of-file character - if supported, use EOF. If not supported, use an explicit length at the start of the string, and document the format.

Note that the string may be of any length (barring RAM limitations).

You must handle direction override characters "properly", in the sense that the directionality of every character must remain the same after reversing the string.

Comment: I need examples for this.

Comment: Can you give a link to the Unicode definition of grapheme clusters?

Comment: Sure: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the direction override characters. Could you give some test cases (preferably with hexdumps of input and output)? What other corner cases are there? On a first read-through I can tell that understanding the definition of *extended grapheme cluster* will take some time, but I'm not clear on whether it covers e.g. emoji type modifiers, emoji families, etc. The definition also makes reference to degenerate cases, and they should be covered by test cases too.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## Difficulty Naming

---

### Introduction

In the game *osu!*, players can make their own beatmaps (levels). The harder the beatmap is, the bigger the *star rating* will be.

Beatmaps have star icons with different colors and letters according to their *star rating*.

*osu!* has also four game modes. The shape of the icon will change depending on the game mode.

### The Challenge

Given a star rating and a gamemode, output the (generally used) difficulty name.

### The Input

- A positive floating-point number (star rating)

  - You can assume the number will never have more than two decimal places.
- A positive integer (game mode)

  - 1 is *Standard*, 2 is *Taiko*, 3 is *Catch the Beat* and 4 is *Mania* (you can use other numbers for the game modes, these are the default.)

### The Output

- A string (difficulty name)

Use this table to determine the output:

[diff table http://image.prntscr.com/image/174e34e56dbb40ad81b209fac3fdc5bc.png](http://image.prntscr.com/image/174e34e56dbb40ad81b209fac3fdc5bc.png)

(if the star rating is exactly 5.25, it counts as *Above 5.25*)

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
- You can take the input either as an array/list, a string separated by commas or spaces, or each number individually.
- Again, you can use other numbers for the game modes.

### Test Cases

```
2.24, 2 ---> Futsuu
1.1, 4 ---> Basic
3.14, 1 ---> Hard
7.0, 3 ---> Overdose
5.0, 4 ---> Exhaust
31415.0, 2 ---> Ura Oni
0.01, 1 ---> Easy
5.25, 1 ---> Expert
```

---

### Sandbox

If you see any grammar errors or anything like that, please tell me, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

## Grow and Visualize Decision Tree

## META: work in progress...

- Would providing the points as an image instead of a list of coordinates simplify the challenge?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)[machine-learning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning)

Given two sets of points in the plane with coordinates `x,y`, both in `[0,1)`, grow a (binary) decision tree as specified below and output a square pixel image of a given size, that visualizes the corresponding tree.

#### How to grow the tree

The we call the two sets here *classes* and follow the following recursive approach:

1. If at least one of the classes is empty, label the current node as a leaf of the nonempty class and stop. Otherwise:
2. First find the mean of each of the x (or y)-coordinates of each of the two classes, and find the mean/center `c` of those two means. Then we partition both classes as follows: All points with an x (or y)-coordinate strictly smaller than `c` belong to *one* half, all the other ones to the other half. The we set the current node to the decision `is the x-cooridinate (or y-coordinate) less than c?`
3. For each of the halves, go back to step 1 and 2, and set the resulting nodes as the child nodes from the current node. If you previously considered the x-coordinates, then consider y-coordinates and vice versa.

[image]

#### How to visualize the tree

We partition the the unit interval `[0,1)` into `N` equidistant sub intervals `[0,1/N), [1/N,2/N), [2/N,3/N)...` and correspondingly the unit square `[0,1)x[0,1)` into squares

```
[i/N,(i+1)/N)x[j/N,(j+1)/N) for i,j=0,1,2,...,N-1
```

which later will be represented by a pixel. For each square `[i/N,(i+1)/N)x[j/N,(j+1)/N)` we classify the point `i/N,j/N` with the tree we just grew and colour the corresponding pixel with the corresponding colour.

For the example above the output would look like so:

[image]

#### Details

- Input: An integer`N>5` and two sets of points in any convenient format (e.g. as two separate list of points, or as a single list with a label for each point etc.) You can assume that in total there is at least one point.
- Output: A pixel image (vector images composed of squares are ok too) of the visualization.

  - You have to choose any two distinct colours, I recommend blue and red.
  - The x-axis should point to the right, the y-axis can point in any direction.
  - The submission should display the image on the screen or save it to a file (like jpg/png/tiff or similar formats)

Comment: 1. The example has the y-axis running upwards, but the text doesn't specify whether that's required. 2. What exactly counts as a "*pixel image*"? In particular, I assume that a 2-dimensional array doesn't, but if you don't rule that out explicitly then someone will probably try it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for the feedback, I added these points. I just had the idea to provide the input points as image, instead of a list of coordinates as a simplificatio.

Answer (score 0):

### Could it all add up to nothing?

Given an input number, return a truthy value if it is possible to arrange permutations of `+` and `-` signs to make the sum of the range up to that value 0.

Note that you don't have to output which set of combinations is truthy.

Test cases:

```
1 (1) --> Falsy
2 (1,2) --> Falsy
3 (1,2,3) --> 1+2-3, Truthy
4 (1,2,3,4) --> -1+2+3-4, Truthy
5 (1,...,5) --> Falsy
6 (1,...,6) --> Falsy
7 (1,...,7) --> 1+2-3-4+5+6-7, Truthy
8 (1,...,8) --> 1+2-3-4-5-6+7+8, Truthy
```

Just one thing - no using `eval` or similar commands.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

#### Sandbox notes

Require a range or a list as input?

Comment: For general lists, I think it would be basically the same as [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51468/help-me-carry-my-shopping-bags). For ranges, I suspect there's a direct criterion.

Comment: @xnor so do I which is why I think it could be more interesting if the pattern could be found. It gets exponentially longer as the lists get longer so is harder to check - better as a fastest algorithm/fastest code?

Comment: I can show that it's exactly the numbers of form `4*n` or `4*n-1`.

Comment: (Ninja'd by xnor) There is probably quite an easy pattern, e.g. if the upper limit is divisible by four, you can always find a zero sum with a "little gauss" argument.

Comment: @xnor I'd love to see a proof=)

Comment: The key is that the pattern `+--+` on four consecutive numbers adds to 0. With `4*n`, just repeat `+--+`. With `4*n-1`, do `+1+2-3`, then repeat `+--+`. With the rest, the sum is odd so it's impossible.

Comment: So saveable? Sounds trivial now.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing xnor's solution would be pretty short.

Answer (score 0):

## Quine-ify PPCG Answers!

Write a program that, when executed, returns the markdown file to your answer.

So, something like this:

```
#Python: 123 bytes

`{insert code here}`
```

## Required things:

- Header must be one hash (`#`)
- The "code part" must be indented with four spaces (or surrounded with backticks if it's a one-liner).
- The code part must be the actual code used to run the program.
- There must be a separation of a newline between the header and the code.
- The program's display bytecount MUST equal the program's actual bytecount.

## Meta:

- **Most importantly: is it even possible, at all?**
- Do I need more clarifications?
- Has this been done already?

Comment: "Most importantly: is it even possible, at all?" Definitely possible and in most languages no more difficult than a standard quine. The points [in this answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/8478) probably apply as well. Also the third-to-last paragraph [in this answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/8478) since languages with longer names will have a disadvantage. And finally, [there's this related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85024/8478) (same thing without the quine part).

Comment: Actually, it's just too easy. Just use a normal quine with stuff before.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make a sequence from a sequence!

*(Title is bad and I should feel bad)*

Given a sequence of positive Integers, take each consecutive pair of two (without taking an element two times) (x,y) and print y x times.

For example for *3,1,4,2*

> 1. Pairs are (3,1) and (4,2)
> 2. (3,1): Print 1 three times: 1 1 1
> 3. (4,2): Print 2 four times: 2 2 2 2
> 4. Resulting sequence/output is *1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2*

**Input**

A sequence of positive integers divisible by two. This can be done by parameters, a *flat* array, an integer stream etc. AS LONG AS there's no nesting or pre-matching of pairs involved.

**Output**

The resulting sequence as showcased above. Same rules for datatypes as declared in input, keep everything flat.

**Test cases**

```
      3, 1, 4, 2 => 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
            6, 5 => 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 => 1, 1, 1
```

**Reference Implementation (Ruby, 55 bytes)**

```
f=->a{a.each_slice(2).collect{|x|Array.new *x}.flatten}
```

Ungolfed:

```
def g *a
  a.each_slice(2).collect do |x|
    Array.new(x[0], x[1]) 
  end.flatten
end
```

The first golfer to find a shorter solution in this language gets a *-1* bonus.

**Scoring**

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: 1. You explicitly mention *printing*. Could a function submission also *return* the array? 2. I recommend dropping the bonus. 3. Can the input be empty or will there be at least one pair?

Comment: This is close enough to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12902/194) that I would cast my supervote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor indeed. Will drop this challenge then.

Answer (score 0):

## CAPTCHAs (Cops and Robbers Style)

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Cops will write a program that generates a CAPTCHA (either through stdin/stdout or on whatever UI is available to your language using only built-ins).

Robbers will attempt to bypass the generated CAPTCHA programmatically, given access to the Cops' programs' stdin/stdout or UI process/thread (for example, in JavaScript, running on the same `document` and `window`).

I need help fleshing this idea out a little more... any suggestions will help.

Comment: How are you going to ensure that captchas are actually captchas, and not an encrypted string turned into an image?  The only way I can think to ensure that we're actually dealing with Captchas is to have humans solve them, which would add another layer of complexity to this challenge.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Well, part of the requirement of a CAPTCHA is that humans should be able to pass the test without just guessing, but I don't know how to make that a more concrete requirement. Perhaps "The required input from an end-user should be visible and somewhat readable in the presented image / ascii-art"?

Comment: Right, that's *super* broad.  Unless you have some sort of test where users actually fill out the captcha, I think its going to remain broad.  (Unless you can think of another way to test)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I could volunteer to test by running and filling out a CAPTCHA, and give objective feedback whenever an answer is posted, saying whether the CAPTCHA cop submission is acceptable or not. Would that be a sufficient test?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It'd be like challenges that say "Write the cleanest code, judged by me".

Comment: @NathanMerrill here's an idea. I can add the [tag:popularity-contest] tag by allowing voting of a cop submission to be based on the human usability. Then I don't have to define exactly what criteria makes a CAPTCHA acceptable.

Comment: That would theoretically work. Historically, though, popularity contests that have worked work because people would vote up based on the "wow factor".  Aka, generate an image with limitation X, and people upvote and say "Wow, that's a impressive rendering".  You'd really have a hard time getting to people vote based on "this is readable", but that's a personal opinion.  I don't think it would be off-topic though.

Answer (score 0):

## Create me a Brainf*** assembler

Write a way to convert "human readable" assembly (of any kind) to Brainf***.
I.E specify a language "X" (which may already exist or may be your own invention), and create a way to map each valid program to a valid Brainf*** program. This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) so the most convenient assembler as evidenced by upvotes wins!

Comment: Convenient is a very broad criterion for judgement. I'd recommend specifying a particular variety of assembly, then make it a code golf challenge.

Comment: @NathanMerill can I specify a specific language I have in mind?

Comment: @NathanMerrill and then make it code golf

Comment: Yes, that would be on topic, but not necessarily interesting, depending on the target language

Comment: https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S that is the target language, and since both BF and S.I.L.O.S are turing complete it seems possible, but challenge

Comment: You would need to include a complete specification of the language on your post, but I have no idea if that would be interesting

Comment: @Nathan Merrill all in all I think it seems to be a ridiculous challenge. Any non tricial in brainf*** is a challenge, now making code to generate non trivial brainf*** is impossible

Comment: @NathanMerrill I will delete this challenge as it seems to be uninteresting?

Comment: It's *much* easier to generate BF than to handwrite it. I don't know if it would be interesting, that's up to the community

Comment: It seems that it is challenging to write any reasonalbly readable environment for assembling to brainf***

Comment: what if I choose X to be Brainfuck or Brainfuck+one extra command.

Comment: Than you would likely lose. @KarlKastor. It is not [tag:code-golf] but rather [tag:popularity-contest]

Answer (score 0):

## King of the golf course

Write a program that golfs Brainf*** programs. Similar to [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges on this site, you will be racing against the clock, and the byte count to maximize glory (reputation).
 Each program will be invoked with a series of command line arguments in this form

```
in out in out in out
```

Each program then has 1000 milliseconds to write a valid brainf*** program to botName.txt. This brainf*** program will take in a null terminated input from stdin and output the respective output according to the table. The code which writes the shortest programs as evidenced by the shortest of 5 runs (or more) will be crowned the winner with a green checkmark. Please note that my languages I support is limited and I may have to download the interpeter. I will have to disqualify non-free interpreters unless volunteers already possessing the interpereter/compiler are willing to help out.

---

Rules

1. You may assume that anywhere from 15-30 in and out pairs will be provided.
2. You may assume that inputs and outputs are valid english words from Random House Dictionary
3. You may assume a non wrapping brainf*** implementation with byte values for cells and a tape size of no less than 30k cells
4. The outputted bf programs may be of any length, but your submission may be no more than 10 kilobytes long (to prevent hardcoding)
5. Invalid submissions will result in immediate disqualification until a bug patch is uploaded

[meta-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-golf)[brainfck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfck) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I'm unsure why this is a KoTH.  Why not simply make it a fastest-code?  Also, I'd recommend making the number of in/out pairs larger (anywhere from 10 to 50).

Comment: @NathanMerrill so should I just make 10 - 50 pairs, and allow anyone to submit their fastest code although programmers with faster computers will win.

Comment: No.  With [tag:fastest-code], one person (probably you) will run the submission themselves (just like in a KoTH) to provide fair scoring.

Comment: @NathanMerril ok sounds good.

Comment: @NathanMerril I will give the programs 1000 milliseconds to output the shortest programs they can, and the average shortest output programs after a few runs wins.

Comment: Hmm.  That sounds more like a [tag:code-challenge] then (just with a time limit)

Answer (score 0):

## Expand constants in a Brainfuck program

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

### Introduction

When golfing in [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), Fred can never remember the shortest
way to write any given constant, and looking it up takes too much time! Luckily,
Fred remembered that PPCG can help! In this challenge, you'll need to
convert base-10 numerals their Brainfuck representations.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes a string of Brainfuck code
containing some numbers, like this:

```
72.>105.>33.
```

and transforms each number into one of its Brainfuck representations, giving (for example) this:

```
-[>+<-------]>-.>+[->-[<]>--]>.>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>.
```

Because Fred has not yet learned the secrets of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, your code must be as small as possible to save
Fred some valuable typing. Fred also wants to win [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contests
with the output, so the code you generate must also be as small as possible.

### Specification

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden; in particular, you cannot scrape
  http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants (or any other site for that
  matter).
- Your program or function may perform I/O through any of the [default I/O
  methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- Assume a wrapping implementation with 1-byte cells (i.e. `-.` gives `ÿ`
  (255)).
- There will never be a number greater than 255 or less than 0 in the input
  (but you do have to handle 0 correctly!). Your program/function must
  handle all numbers 0-255 (inclusive).
- You may assume that there are as many temporary cells as necessary to the
  right of the pointer location (but not the left).
- You may assume that the cell where a number will go and all temporary
  cells are set to 0.
- When substituting a number, the pointer must end at the cell with the number.
  All temporary cells must be reset to 0.
- You may assume that there will never be any non-Brainfuck, non-digit
  characters in the input, and that the input will never be empty (i.e. the
  input will match `/^[,\.\[\]+\-<>0-9]+$/`).

### Test Cases

The test cases given below are the output for a program/function using the shortest "wrapping" version of the constants at http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants.

```
Input
Output
Brainfuck program's output

72.>105.>33.
-[>+<-------]>-.>+[->-[<]>--]>.>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>.
Hi!

255>10++>65>255<+[-<+]->[-+[->+]-<.+[-<+]->]
->++++++++++++>>+[+[<]>>+<+]>>-<+[-<+]->[-+[->+]-<.+[-<+]->]
AAAAAAAAAAAA

>0>48-->255<[>>86.[-]+[-<+]-<-]
>>-[>+<-----]>----->-<[>>-[>+<---]>+.[-]+[-<+]-<-]
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

>,[>,]<[<]>[.>]
>,[>,]<[<]>[.>]
(cat - outputs the input)
```

### Scoring

Your score is your byte count plus the average length of your program/function's output for each number. For example, if a 30 byte program's output had an average length of 13.5, its score would be `30 + 13.5 = 43.5`.

### Helpful Hints

- http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants

---

### Sandbox Questions

Is it tagged correctly? Should this be [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) instead of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)?

Comment: To prevent hardcoding, add the length of the output to their score

Comment: I don't understand "*the code you generate must also be as small as possible.*" The spec requires using the "*shortest Brainfuck representation according to http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants*", so the code generated should be identical for every valid answer, surely?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oops! Forgot to remove all references to that URL. I'll fix that now. It's meant to be optional to use it, a previous version of the spec required it.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert hexagonal coordinates to index

Your job is to, given the size of the hexagon and a pair of axial coordinates, return the index as if all the rows were laid out side by side.

Here's an example mapping for size 3:

```
(q,r), 3

       (0,0) (1,0) (2,0)
    (-1,1) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1)
(-2,2) (-1,2) (0,2) (1,2) (2,2)
   (-2,3) (-1,3) (0,3) (1,3)
      (-2,4) (-1,4) (0,4)

maps to

    00 01 02
  03 04 05 06
07 08 09 10 11
 12 13 14 15
  16 17 18
```

Here's the formula I found (could be improved):

```
i=index
s=size

i = q + sum( ( 2 * s - 0.5 - abs( x - s + 0.5 ) ) for x in 1..r )
```

Test cases (0-based indexing):

```
(q, r, s) -> i

(0, 0, 1)  -> 0
(0, 0, 50) -> 0
(0, 3, 3)  -> 14
(-3, 5, 4) -> 28
(5, 2, 12) -> 18
```

---

Meta notes:

- Should I include links to axial coordinates and centered hexagonal numbers?

  - Or, instead, should I explain axial coordinates better?
- Should I include the formula I came up with?
- More test cases, or are those fine?
- More exposition?
- I'm also planning to do a challenge the other way around, is that ok?

Comment: This technically isn't related to Hexagony (though, you can keep the reference if you'd like).  I personally wouldn't include the formula, but that's my opinion.  The reverse challenge seems like a good one as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Rules

- Your program must take no input and print [this text](http://pastebin.com/raw/SBMNH0gJ).
- You can have trailing newlines, and spaces after lines.
- You must not use a builtin or load the text for an external resource.

## Score

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Did you guess what was the text?

Comment: 10/10 very creative and interesting

Comment: What is special about the text and means that the answers won't use the exact same techniques as previous [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to print the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) ([A033307](https://oeis.org/A033307)) indefinitely.

There must be no spaces in your output and the solution with the fewest bytes wins!

Comment: 1. The Cham-whatever constant has infinitely many digits, making this challenge the same as [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63834/48934)

Comment: 2. [Duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63834/48934).

Comment: @LeakyNun To prevent this being a duplicate could the challenge be "Print the Champernowne constant in base n", where the input is the base?

Comment: Also, this question isn't self contained. If you were to post an acceptably modified version of this, please explain what this constant/sequence is within the question itself, even if there is a link

Answer (score 0):

### Paint with all the colors of the RGB rainbow

<sup>Inspired by [Images with all colors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22144/45941) and [American Gothic in the palette of Mona Lisa: Rearrange the pixels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33172/45941)</sup>

Given an input raster image, output a raster image where each pixel is a unique color, such that the sum of the absolute value of the sum of the differences of the RGB channel values for each pixel between the original image and the output image is minimized. In other words, that means, given an image `O`, find an image `X` such that every pixel is a different color, and (in pseudo-Python) the quantity `sum(abs(O_pixel.RED - X_pixel.RED) + abs(O_pixel.GREEN - X_pixel.GREEN) + abs(O_pixel.BLUE - X_pixel.BLUE) for O_pixel,X_pixel in zip(O.pixels, X.pixels))` is minimized.

### 3-bit example

All images in this example are 4 pixels wide by 2 pixels high, magnified 40x to 160x80 so that they can be seen more easily.

Original image:

[image: original 3-bit]

The palette:

[image: color space]

The image using each color from the palette that is closest to the original (minimum sum 6):

[image: 3-bit output big]

### Specifications

- All images will use 8-bit colors (3 bits in the red and green channels and 2 in the blue channel), and will be 16x16. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/256colour.png) is an image displaying the 8-bit color palette. Each color from this palette must be used exactly once in the output image.
- Submissions must complete for any of the test images in under 1 minute.
- If there are multiple optimal solutions, any one of them may be used.

### Test cases

Original is on the left, expected output is on the right. All of these images are zoomed in; click the links to get the original-sized images.

[image] [image]

Note that these two are the same, because the original image is already composed of unique pixels. Thus, the minimum sum is 0.

(more to come once my computer finishes generating them)

Comment: 1. If you want the test cases to be useful - and if you don't, there's no point in having them - then include the minimum sum of the absolute pixel differences. 2. I don't see the point of using images. The objective function prioritises red completely over green and green completely over blue, so there's no reason for the output image to look remotely like the input one. The interesting part of the question could be done perfectly well with integer arrays, and that would allow for much simpler I/O.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right on the pixel differences being dominated by the red channel - what I had in my mind was not what I typed up. I'll edit it to closer reflect my original idea that got lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

***Smallest Vigenere cypher executable***

**Brief**

Impliment a Vigenere cypher program in your favourite language to create the smallest compiled program in any operating system.

For people unfamilar with a Vigenere cypher program, please visit the following link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher

**Scoring**

- Your score is the size in bytes of the folder that contains the main executable.

To find this, you must first compile your program. Secondly, delete any files unecessary to the running of your program. Finally, right-click on or list details by command line the folder (or equivalent standard action depending on operating system) containing the compiled executable and note the smallest of the listed size (e.g. size or size on disc in Windows) in bytes value.

- If dlls or similar are referenced, then their size in bytes must be added to the score.
- Interpreted languages may be used, but the size of a compatible interpreter (e.g. a web browser if using javascript) must be included when calculating the score.

**Specific details**

The program must accept 3 arguments:

- Argument 1 must be either 'e' or 'd', with e meaning encrypt and d meaning decrypt
- Argument 2 is the keyword string.
- Argument 3 is the main input string.
- If Argument 1 is 'e' then Argument 3 is the message to be encoded.
- If Argument 1 is 'd' then Argument 3 is the message to decoded.

The program must output the result only:

- If Argument 1 is 'e' then the result is the encoded string.
- If Argument 1 is 'd' then the result is the decoded string.

**Rules**

- The earliest dated post with the lowest score wins.
- In your answer post, post enough information so that others may repeat steps described to arrive at the same result. Presume that people reading your answer are fluent in your chosen language, but may not necesarilly understand any nifty tricks or exploits.
- Include your score in your answer post to let everyone know your score.
- You may post all your source-code if you like, but may also post only the parts that you feel are significant. There is no need to post automatically generated code, although if it is generated by a plugin then this should discussed. Failure to do so is considered cheating.
- Edits may not be made to answers. If you have made a mistake then delete and repost your answer anew.
- All edits and mistakes are considered cheating. Cheat answers are identified by members of the community leaving a comment. Cheat answers must be deleted, corrected and reposted.
- The community must use the comments to report cheating only. Be careful reporting cheats as a mistake may result in a good answer being deleted.
- Improvements should be listed as a new answer post.
- Take the competition seriously and be a good sport. Avoid ribbing, jokes or childish remarks.
- Have fun

Comment: This excludes languages that can't be compiled (such as Python and lots of esolangs), the input format seems overly cumbersome and I can't see from a first glance where you define what your score actually is (but thanks for using the sandbox)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! And welcome to the Sandbox... I find this a great place to learn what works and what doesn't, as often ideas I present have already been tried previously. I'll give some feedback on various points that have already been discussed by the community previously. Please feel very welcome to drop in to [chat] and talk things over with the friendly people there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Interpreted or partially compiled languages may now be used and I have attempted to make the scoring system more obvious by putting it closer top the top under its own heading.

Comment: This appears to be a *sizecoding* challenge (scored based on executable size rather than source code size). There has been [previous discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/are-sizecoding-questions-on-topic) on meta about this scoring method. Note that this is not off topic, but it might help to see the discussion in case it affects your decision on how to score this.

Comment: At the moment any answer that isn't compiled has already lost due to bloat of the interpreter. C/Assemblies will probably win. Actually Java has a decent chance because there are old mobile phone OS's that can run Java bytecode natively

Comment: It helps to include a brief description of the task, for the benefit of people who are not yet familiar with it, and sometimes a link to further information. For example, the [Wikipedia page on Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

Comment: Is the code to be posted in an answer the compiled code or the source code that compiles to it?

Comment: This is your challenge, so you make the rules, but just to let you know, asking for improved versions to be posted as new answers is unusual. Every post has an edit history that is viewable by everyone, which also makes it possible to see clearly when a given score was achieved (in case you were worried that an edited answer would appear to have achieved that score at the time it was first posted). It is common practice in most challenges to edit in new improvements, and people often comment to suggest improvements to each other (this community is both very competitive and very helpful...).

Comment: [Related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86986/print-a-tabula-recta) (not a duplicate - just for information)

Comment: 1. [More closely related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/678/194). If this question were [tag:code-golf] then it's close enough that I would consider it a dupe. 2. As it stands, I would vote to close as lacking an objective winning criterion. The size of the dlls loaded by an answer vary according to a lot of factors which are outside the control of the author. If my score could change because a security update to my Linux distro changes the size of `libc.so` then I need to write a mini-thesis on precisely what conditions must be met to get the claimed score.

Comment: What do you think to a handicap based on the language used? On one hand, I don't want to exclude people that like a particular language, but on the other hand I don't want to be unfair to people that code closer to the metal in c or assembler.

Comment: It is not unfair; everyone understands that lower level languages are ueually longer (with the exception of the high level languages Java and C#), but that doesn't stop people from golfing well in low level languages, and compiled executables are perfectly valid submissions.

Comment: I'll take that to mean that you would indeed like me to condsider a handicap, although this isn't strictly code golf. More like code crystal maze (sadly, without richard o brien or edward tudor pole as host for the time being). Well, my point is that since I want the score to based on how the system is effected as a whole, whereas code golf is much simpler. I'll get to the drawing board, and see if I can come up with a scoring system as close to simple as possible that still makes this a fun game for all.

Answer (score 0):

## N-ary Time

[Decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_time) is a concept of having days, hours, minutes, and seconds relate to each other by powers of 10:

N-ary time, which I made up, is having days, hours, minutes, and seconds relate to each other by powers of N.

Given an input N where minumum(2^31-1, [languages upper limit on integers])>N>1, output the value of an N-ary hour, N-ary minute and N-ary second, in seconds, using these rules:
*There are N^1 (10 in base-N) N-ary hours in a day, there are N^2 (100 in base-N) N-ary minutes in an N-ary hour, and there are N^2 (100 in base-N) N-ary seconds in an N-ary minute.*

**There are 86400 regular seconds in a day.**

### Input

Input must be an integer, [inputted in anyway allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

### Output

Output consists of floats or integers that represent the amount of seconds in each N-ary unit within 0.5 seconds . Order is irrelevant.

### Test cases

```
input-->output

2-->[43200.0, 10800.0, 2700.0] (or some other way of representing the data)

8-->10800 3 169 (numbers don't have to have specific order)

3-->28800.3200.356 (note that this might have the same character as decimal points, but it's still clear that they are three separate numbers)
```

Comment: All makes sense, but it took me a while to grasp how the output follows from the input. A worked example might help.

Comment: Probably should have had the amount of seconds in a day yes

Comment: You could say something like "For example, when N=2, there are 2 hours in a day, 2 squared = 4 minutes in an hour, and 2 squared = 4 seconds in a minute. That makes a 2-mal hour 43,200 standard seconds, a 2-mal minute 10,800 standard seconds, and a 2-mal second 2,700 standard seconds."

Comment: 1. Why invent *n-mal* when *n-ary* is a perfectly good word and already in  wide usage? 2. IMO "*Given `n` output `86400/n`, `86400/n^3`, and `86400/n^5`*" is too trivial to make a worthwhile question.

Comment: I might think about a formula for the amount of n-ary hours that's less trivial soon

Answer (score 0):

## Floating Point Error

Given a basic arithmetic problem, the division, multiplication, addition, or subtraction of two numbers (which are representable in a 32bit floating point), output the percent difference between the actual (mathematical) result and the nearest floating point value. The percent difference should be rounded to a whole number.

You may use either 32bit or 64bit floating point following the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

The percent difference is calculated in the following manner:

100 * (*Actual* - *Float*) / *Actual*

You may round to a whole number in any of three ways, as long as you only use one method: (1) floor, (2) ceiling, (3) nearest.

**Examples** and **Test Cases**, yet to come.

Comment: This is also known as the *relative error*.

Comment: As currently specified, I think that the following is an almost fully compliant answer in CJam: `0`. Note that I'm choosing to use 64-bit floating point, so an error of 1 ulp corresponds to 2^-29 ulps of the original 32-bit inputs, which is considerably less than 1%. The only test cases which I think this fails are ones where *Actual* is 0 and the output should be either an infinity or NaN.

Answer (score 0):

### Bomb Drops

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [tag:???]

#### The Challenge

Your task is to create a program that simulates "dropping bombs" on a 2 dimensional array.

For example consider the following 2d array:

```
3 0 5 0 5
5 3 4 0 2
1 0 5 4 2
2 4 2 3 2
2 3 3 0 0
```

Dropping a bomb on a single cell decreases the value of that cell by 2 and the value of its direct neighbors (including diagonal neighbors) by 1, to a minimum of 0.

If we were to drop on a bomb on the cell corresponding to `array[2][1]` where the value is `4`, or coords `(2,1)`, then the new 2d array would look like so:

```
3 0 4 0 5
5 2 2 0 2
1 0 4 3 2
2 4 2 3 2
2 3 3 0 0
```

#### Input

Your input will be a two dimensional array of integers greater than or equal to zero, in whatever way you like.

You will then also take input that is a sequence of tuples, lists of size 2, or whatever else you please that corresponds to coordinate points. For example,

```
(2,1),(3,4),(0,0) or [2,1],[3,4],[0,0] or 2,1,3,4,0,0
```

For each of these points, you will simulate a bomb drop on that point. You do not need to worry about these coordinates being out of range of the 2d array.

#### Output

Output consists of a two-dimensional array, formatted the way you please.

#### Test Cases

```
>>> [[0, 1, 3, 1, 1], [3, 5, 1, 0, 4], [1, 1, 1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3, 4], [5, 2, 0, 2, 2]]
# 0 1 3 1 1
# 3 5 1 0 4
# 1 1 1 0 2
# 1 2 0 3 4
# 5 2 0 2 2
>>> [3,4],[2,1],[0,0]
0 0 2 0 1
2 3 0 0 4
1 0 0 0 2
1 2 0 2 3
5 2 0 0 1

# You can also take input in one pass, rather than 
# having the 2d array and the coordinates be seperate inputs:
>>> [[5, 2, 3, 0, 3], [4, 3, 5, 5, 5], [1, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2, 2, 4]],[2,2],[0,1],[3,3]
# 5 2 3 0 3
# 4 3 5 5 5
# 1 3 3 3 3
# 0 1 2 3 1
# 3 1 2 2 4
4 1 3 0 3
2 1 4 4 5
0 1 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 0
3 1 1 1 3
```

#### Other info

Inspired from [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300149/bomb-dropping-algorithm).

---

This is my first challenge, I'm looking for any advice at all. I'm not sure what other tags to put aside from code golf. I'm probably missing a few basic rules etc too that I've forgotten about. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good challenge, but I'd consider rewriting the parts about  "bomb dropping." This is just my opinion, but I feel like adding deadly weapons to an otherwise lighthearted post about programming detracts from the challenge.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It makes for a good clickbait title though :P

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Fair point, what would you suggest?

Comment: You could consider something like "fill up the holes" where bombs are replaced by bags of dirt and the numbers are depth below ground level or "clean up the garbage" where you grab from piles that are nearby each other. Unfortunately I'm having trouble coming up with something quite as evocative as bombs are. If you can't come up with a good replacement, I wouldn't worry too much about my original comment, as there's nothing actually wrong with your post. I just felt the tone was kind of off.

Answer (score 0):

### How far is it?

I have no children myself but I understand they are more interested in the destination than the journey, so often ask how much of the journey is left. This might be a car trip, or it might be a demonstration of the Tower of Hanoi puzzle.

The original aim of the puzzle is to move all the disks from one pillar to another, but except for the smallest disk (which can be moved to any pillar at any time) the only disk you can move is the lowest numbered disk on the other two pillars.

Although there is a well-known optimal sequence from one pillar to another, each of the three moves will take you slightly nearer to finishing on a different pillar. (This partly explains why there are only two available moves when all the disks are already on the same pillar.) It's therefore possible to mistakenly take a detour towards another pillar yet correct yourself and finish at your desired pillar without retracing your steps. You should therefore not assume that the input position is from the optimal sequence.

The challenge is to write a program or function that accepts three sets (arrays, lists, strings, etc.) representing the sizes of the disks on each pillar and returns an integer giving the number of steps remaining to move all the disks to the first pillar. Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3] [0] [] -> 1
[2, 3] [0, 1] [] -> 3
[0, 1] [2] [3] -> 11
[0, 1, 2] [] [3] -> 15
```

Not only must your program return the shortest number of steps possible, but it must itself also be as short as possible.

Please indicate whether your input format requires the disks in a particular order.

Comment: 1. Needs at least a link to an explanation of the tower of Hanoi, and preferably a short explanation in the question so that it's self-contained. 2. The test cases don't seem to cover situations where poor play has got the board into a complete mess.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert Between American and British English Spellings

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

---

In this challenge, you will have to write two programs or functions. One will convert a list of words from their American English spelling to the British English equivalent, and the other to convert the other way. Here's that catch: you only have **300 bytes to do both**!

### The Challenge

You can find a gist [**here**](https://gist.github.com/GamrCorps/5e7dd531df99be4408bd768ded36aad9) that contains a list of **1000** words. The file is formatted so each line is `british-spelling(space)american-spelling`. Therefore, there are only **500** words in total, each with **2** spellings. This file is for your convenience, and it was based on the list found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_spelling_variants).

Your challenge is to write two programs or functions (has to be two programs or two functions, it can't be one program and one function). Both will take a single string as input and output a single string. The first program/function will take in British English words and output the American English spelling, and the second will take in American English words and output the British English spelling. **Built-in functions or libraries that do this task are not allowed, nor are standard loopholes.** You also cannot hard-code the list into your program. Your programs and functions have a shared 300 byte limit, i.e. `length(program1)+length(program2)<=300`. However, each program/function may be of different length.

### Scoring

You will be scored based on how accurate your programs/functions were. Your score will be calculated based on the following formula:

[image: formula]

Highest score wins. Ties are broken by shortest shared byte total.

---

***SANDBOX NOTES***

- *I can't help but fell like I am missing something.*
- *Should I post the gist contents here, as well as a link to it?*
- *Is 300 bytes too generous, too litte, or is it fine?*
  -

Comment: [Byte limits are frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8928/55896)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Well, my main concern is that solutions will be able to get high or perfect scores without a byte limit. My main goal with the limit was to simply encourage use of a few creative methods that don't have really high scores rather than allowing all programs to have high scores. AKA, I want to increase the variance in the scores.

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon I don't think that's really applicable to this question - byte limits tend to be useful for [tag:test-battery] for the reasons GamrCorps says. Whether 300 is generous or too little however, is hard to say without actually trying...

Comment: Byte limits are redundant and unhelpful for a code golf challenge, but the meta post isn't saying byte limits are bad elsewhere. This isn't a code golf so the byte limit isn't bad for the same reason. However, I would point out that 300 bytes is very little for Java, but probably more than enough to write a fully working bilingual AI in Jelly. This isn't necessarily a problem - competition can be within languages rather than between them. However, it might be difficult to find a limit that doesn't completely exclude a lot of languages.

Comment: As Sp3000 points out, it will be difficult to fine tune the limit, but I do think this is an interesting challenge. There is a lot of overlap in the patterns of how British and American spellings vary, so this isn't just an arbitrary compression challenge.

Comment: I have no idea which would be more interesting, but just thinking: The word list could be solely words that differ between the two countries, or it could include some words that are the same in both. Does anyone have any thoughts about what effect this would have?

Answer (score 0):

## Left and Right

Given an input string, in ASCII, output ")|]" as many times as the case-insensitive word "right" appears in input, and output "(|[" as many times as the case-insensitive word "left" appears in input. The order is irrelevant. If and only if no occurences of these words are in input, output "X|X". **Spacing between items is optional**

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), less bytes is best

Test cases:

```
input -> output
RightRightighteftleft -> (|[ )|] )|], or some other ordering
this doesn't contain either word -> X|X
LEfT, LeFT, leFT, righT -> (|[ (|[ (|[ )|]
(|[ -> X|X
```

Answer (score 0):

## Enumerate Irreducible Polynomials in GF(2)[X]

### Meta:

- I noticed this is a duplicate of [Find the XOR Primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66911/find-the-xor-primes)
- Would it make it a non-dupe if we'd go from `q=2` to `q=3`?
- Would it be more interesting for the general case, where the submissions have to take `q`(prime) *and* `n`

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)[polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra)

A polynomial over any finite field `GF(q)` of prime order `q` can be represented by an integral polynomial with coefficients in `{0,1,2,...,q-1} ⊂ ℤ` by the reduction modulo `q`. This allows us to easily enumerate all polynomials with coefficients in that field by using a polynomial `p` with coefficients in `{0,1,2,...,q-1} ⊂ ℤ` and evaluating it in `q`. So we map such a polynomial `p` to a nonnegative integer `p(q)`. It is easy to show that this mapping is a bijection between the set of said polynomials and the nonnegative integers, when you consider one of those polynomials `p(X)` as an integer in base `X`.

#### Challenge

Let `I` be the set of irreducible polynomials with coefficients in `GF(2)`, represented by integral polynomials with coefficients in `{0,1}`. Then enumerate all elements of `{p(2) | p ∊ I} ⊂ ℤ` in ascending order and let `a(n)` be the `n`th element. Given `n` your submission should return `a(n)`. This is in fact [A014580](http://oeis.org/A014580) in OEIS.

#### Examples

The irreducible polynomials in `GF(2)[X]` with a degree of at most 3 are: `{p1(X)=X, p2(X)=1+X, p3(X)=1+X+X^2}`. Substituting `X` by `2` results in `p1(2)=2, p2(2)=3, p3(2)=7`. So we see `a(1) = 2, a(2) = 3, a(3)=7`. Some more of those polynomials can be found on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html).

#### Test cases

```
 n  a(n)
 1    2
 2    3
 3    7
 4   11
 5   13
 6   19
 7   25
20  103
34  203
35  211
50  355
53  369
54  375
```

Comment: It should be a polynomial *over* any finite field: the field which it's *in* is `GF(q)[x]`, as per the title. I'm not sure what the point of the first sentence is: it seems to be stating a tautology. Unless it's intended to define *a polynomial over a field `F`* as *a polynomial whose coefficients are in `F`*? I'm also not sure what you mean by "*evaluating it in `q`*". As for the question about dupes: over prime-order Galois fields other than `GF(2)` there isn't a built-in for polynomial addition in most languages, but implementing that manually instead of with `^` is fairly minor.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the correction. With that sentence I wanted to emphasize that it is sufficient to consider these (integer) representants of the residue classes as elements of the field. *A polynomial p evaluated in q* is just the image of `q` under the substitution homomorphism `q ↦ p(q)` defined by `p`. You "plug in a value for X".

Comment: I would call that evaluation *at* `q` (or possibly *at `x=q`* for extra clarity).

Comment: Have thought about it some more. It seems to me that you're trying to be overly clear, in the sense that I think you're trying to distinguish the element `2` of `GF(3)` from the element `2` of `ℤ`. Non-mathematicians are just going to get confused, and mathematicians are used to using the notation which makes sense and only distinguishing the elements of the different fields when it's really important. I propose the following for the first paragraph (with a footnote at the bottom of the question):

Comment: The finite field `GF(q)` of prime order `q` can be thought of as the integers `{0,1,...,q-1}` with addition and multiplication modulo `q`.<sup>[1]</sup> So a polynomial `p` over the field `GF(q)` is also a polynomial over the integers. If we evaluate `p(q)` over the integers, we are performing a base conversion of the coefficients of `p` in base `q`, and this gives a bijection between polynomials over `GF(q)` and the nonnegative integers.

Comment: <sup>[1]</sup> NB There are finite fields of prime power order `GF(q^a)`, `a > 1`, but they don't have the same multiplication structure as the integers modulo `q^a`.

Answer (score 0):

## Simulate Bibliomancy

In this challenge, you must take input as a string, and output a random word. Please note that you cannot simply take a random number and take the item of the list at that index: You will be simulating pages.

Also note that rather than your program picking from the page with eyes closed (which would bias towards larger words), it will generate a random number, and pick the word corresponding to that number

Pages will be some amount characters long, according to input (*sandbox: I need help with how pages are distinct (are they assumed to be separate, or do pages need to have truncated length if a word is too long)*). Every page has an equal chance of being picked (assume the PRNG is even), and every word on the page as an equal chance of being picked. In this way, a word from a grandiloquent page, with fewer words, is more likely to be chosen than a word from a page with many short words, and all the words on a page have an equal chance of being chosen. The sum of the chances of picking any word from one page is equal to the sum of the chances of picking any word from another page.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), this is that

---

Of course, this still needs clarification. Halp sandbox

Comment: So the challenge is: Given a string describing the text of a book and an int describing the number of pages, divide the text into pages and pick a random word from a random page?

Comment: Yeah, that probably is a better explanation than mine

Comment: The difficulty of the challenge will be decides by how you decide that words which end up in the middle of a page split should be handled. Max chars per page would be another way of doing it as well. Would also change difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

## The grand golfed double radiation-hardened quine [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Yep. It's quite a mouthful.

- **Double radiation-hardened** - removing any two characters still results in a valid quine.
- **Quine** - a program that outputs itself

### Rules

- No reading from a file or from the web - that's cheating!
- Standard loopholes apply.
- File must be at least two characters long.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

I've seen singly radiation hardened quines before. Now it's your job to make doubly radiation hardened ones.

---

Please constructively criticize this challenge.

Comment: This is a duplicate; [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57257/62131) is about generalized radiation-hardened quines, and there's already one that can survive three removals there.

Answer (score 0):

## Time-Quine Time!

Your task is to write a quine (I know, I know, old stuff. But bear with me for a moment) which waits for a certain amount of time after the start of its execution, then prints its own source-code.

Rules:

- Standard Loopholes apply
- Your program must always halt for the same amount of time before printing its source code (System independent)

Input

- Your program should take no input

Output

- The programs exact source code (After the wait)

Scoring:

- This is code-golf, so shortest code wins, BUT:
- The time your program waits before printing is also taken into account. SO:
- Your score is equal to `length of code (in bytes) / log(base 10)(time in seconds of wait)`
- Code golf, so shortest code wins

P.S.: Please indicate in your answer how long your code will wait for

---

All feedback is appreciated

Comment: Does a solution have to call a sleep() function or can it make some calculations (that would take a different amount of time on different machines)?

Comment: The time it takes should always be the same and system-independent, so a sleep() call or similar would probably be the only way to do it.

Comment: Why is the wait duration relevant for scoring? Is this just some weird handcapping mechanism to favour languages with a `sleepNanos` method?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Should have been divided by. Fixed now. It's supposed to favor longer wait times.

Comment: Then I can get my score as low as I want by just adding more 9s to the wait time, because the numerator increases linearly and the denominator increases geometrically.

Comment: @PeterTaylor True. Any suggestions for making the denominator increase less than the numerator?

Comment: I don't think there is any fix, and I don't think it's interesting enough to be worth trying to fix anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Square pegs in round holes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Does a square peg fit through a round hole? Let's find out ...

#### Input

- Two 3-tuples, describing a circle and a square on the [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) plane.
- They're represented here by the form `(x, y, r)` and `(X, Y, S)`.
- For both tuples, `x` and `y` are integers representing the center of the corresponding shape.
- The `r` and `S` will only be positive integers numbers, with `r` representative of the radius of the circular hole, while `S` is the length of the side of the square.
- The square is oriented parallel to the x and y axes -- i.e., the left and right sides of the square parallel the y axis, and the top and bottom sides of the square parallel the x axis.

*(Meta: is this sufficient to describe the shapes?)*

#### Output

- A [truthy/falsey value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/42963), written to STDOUT or returned, indicating whether the square peg will fit through the round hole.
- The square can only fit through the round hole if the *entirety* of the square is completely enclosed in the circle -- no points of the square can intersect or lay outside the circle.
- Both objects are fixed at their corresponding centers (no rotating or translating about the origin allowed).
- Precision within usual 32-bit floating point is sufficient.

#### Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- The input numbers can be taken via [any suitable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

```
(x, y, r) (X, Y, S) -> result  # explanation
(1, 1, 1) (0, 0, 1) -> false   # square is offset from circle
(1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 1) -> true    # square easily fits in the circle
(1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 2) -> false   # some of the square is outside the circle
```

Comment: 1. Why floating point? It isn't necessary, and it excludes a lot of languages. 2. How can the result be ambiguous?

Comment: Elaboration: what this boils down to is: given `(X, Y, S)` and `(x, y, r)`, check for `i` and `j` in `{0, 1}` whether `(x - X - S*i)^2 + (y - Y - S*j)^2 < r^2`. There's nothing there which can't be done in integers. An answer in (to pick a language with compile-time typing) Java which used floating point could be converted to an answer which uses integers just by changing some types and (if doing input from stdin) switching the parse method. Moreover, every test case which uses non-integer values can be converted to a test case which uses (potentially large) integers by simple scaling.

Comment: On the other point, I don't think "*ambiguous*" is the correct word for the situation you describe with rounding error. If input is in 32-bit floats then I think that promotion to 64-bit floats would be sufficient to guarantee a correct result. (If not then an 80-bit float would definitely be sufficient). In order to have a clear spec, I think you should really define the permitted error - although I note that it can only really be an issue with corners of the square which are very nearly axis-aligned with the centre of the circle and very near its edge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the detailed explanation -- you solved the problem in a different method than I had (briefly) sketched out, hence why I was hung up on floating point requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Print this text in as few bytes as you can

```
**********
****  ****
***    ***
**      **
*        *
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
```

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: Seems boring but you can make it more interesting by having to generate the pattern in size n given n as input

Comment: I think fixed-output ASCII arts are fine, but I'd scale this up a bit because it might be hard to beat hardcodes or partial hardcodes in verbose languages. I also suggest doing a thorough dupe check.

Comment: IMO it's a dupe of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8696/194).

Comment: Somehow partial duplicate of [Print an arch of ascending / descending numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11640/print-an-arch-of-ascending-descending-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

## Enterprise Quality Code!

### Summary of this challenge

**Print** (to make it more fair when competing with another language changing the output method could be a trivial way to golf) the first N Prime numbers. Your score will be the sum of the byte counts of all entries which no one has been able to golf down (by removing one or more characters and rearrange the program). If you golf down someones program, post it as another submission. 
You may not golf your own programs once submitted.

---

This is not a [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/the-bowlers-golfers-fraction-war) because it significantly changes the scoring method. Writing code which allows a single byte to be golfed off will cost the **whole** of the score. Also as this is a [rosseta-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosseta-code) challenge the winner is likely going to have high scores across a multitude of languages. It is likely that scores will be incredibly near 30k for each language. This limit allows a more interesting competition as it prevents submissions of exponentially large lengths.

---

#### Back-story and explanation

At Pretty Good consultants there is a focus on writing "quality" verbose code that is sufficiently engineered. Your boss has decided to test you on your skills.

---

Consider the set of all [programming languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/46918) in existence before the posting of this challenge. For this challenge there will technically be one individual "winner" in each language, however the boss will give a <s>promotion</s> accepted tick mark to only one answer based on your score.

---

The goal of this challenge is to [receive](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) an integer N strictly smaller than 2^16-1 and print the first N prime numbers (in less than 24 hours) separated by your platforms choice of new line. [OEIS sequence A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040) in as **many bytes** as possible in as many languages as possible. However, note that others vying for the promotion will try to "help" you by **golfing** down your score.

Sample output for an input 11

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
```

---

### How to participate

Pick any language X, but please avoid selecting a language which is just another version or derivative of another answer. 
If there is no existing answer in language X than you will write a program (which must fit into a single post) that solves this challenge. 
The length in bytes of the source (in any reasonable preexisting textual encoding) will be **added** to your score. You must avoid using any unnecessary characters for reasons that will soon become apparent.


If language X already has been used to answer this question, then you must answer using any permutation of any proper subset of the characters used in the shortest answer (I.E take the shortest X answer and remove some (>=1) characters and optionally rearrange the resulting code). The previous holder of the shortest X answer will lose **all** of the bytes provided by his answer from his score, and the number of bytes of your submission will now be added to your score. The number of bytes golfed off gets "lost" forever.

---

Clarifications <s>shamelessly lifted</s> adapted from this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37464/write-a-polyquine)

#### Rules for Languages

Languages used should be distinctly different. A language is different iff:

- It is not a different version of another language (Java 7, Java 8)
- They must not be derived from another language (Branf*** versus Alphf***)
- One language may not be a subset or superset or trivial  of the other one (e.g. hq9+ versus [hq9+b](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2BB)).

HQ9+ wouldnt be a language anyway, but please be judicious when selecting a language, if you have any clarifications on a language that may be significantly different from an existing answer please ping me and we can work it out.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[rosetta-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-code)[sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences)

Comment: If anyone knows how to make a scoreboard for this I will be much obliged

Comment: So the highest score wins, overall (from all your still-valid answers). And when you outgolf somebody, they lose their points, you gain your points, but do you get the points that they lost?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk the way I had it planned out is that the amount of bytes golfed off is forever lost. I don't know if thats fair but that essentially prevents people from "profiting" off of ridiculous answers that were not fortified against being golfed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. You might want to clarify that a bit though. I really like the idea.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk clarifications added, let me know if this is ready for main

Comment: It might be ready, but you should wait for somebody else to also give input.

Comment: All right sounds good

Comment: 1. So basically the accepted answer goes to the shortest answer in Unary? 2. The tags [tag:code-golf] and [tag:code-bowling] are mutually exclusive. This isn't really either.

Comment: @PeterTaylor please read the whole thing. The answer must fit within 30k

Comment: If someone can write a brainf*** program that is only about 6 chars long or so than they deserve the accept tick

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala [Golunar wins](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar)

Comment: @EasterlyIrk lol thats actually just a compressed form of Brainf*** it probably wouldn't score that well

Comment: @PeterTaylor essentially I restrict answers to fit in one post which means the best score for a single language is slightly under 30 characters

Comment: 30k not 30 my bad

Comment: I find the intro confusing. I didn't understand what the challenge is broadly about until reading to the end. Can you cleanly state the challenge at the beginning, and move the details later?

Comment: Ok editing, @xnor

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala It's brainfuck, but shorter. With a simple brainfuck code that's golfed, it will most likely stay intact for the duration.

Comment: I think this is a [dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37797/20260) actually. Different task, same cops and robbers format. The tricks should be mostly the same, of using a huge number of one character as data.

Comment: @xnor it is similar, but not a dupe. Here it is imperative to not let any characters get golfed off at all, and by being a robber you impicitly become a cop. Plus all submissions must fit into the 30k post limit placing a hard limit on bowled answers.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Sorry, I'm not sold the difference. The changes seem minor. The 30k post limit does stop the exponentially huge answers, but they can still push the same massive-string trick as close to 30k as they can.

Comment: @xnor well also this is a [tag:rosetta-code] which also requires participants to try and score in multiple languages. Posting a 30k answer which gets 1k bytes golfed off will end up costing you the whole of the 30k. The winners of this challenge will be holding the titles in multiple languages and will possibly score 30/30k score on multiple answers

Comment: Will the overall winner be the single answer post with the highest score? Or will the overall winner be the person who has the highest score summed over all their answer posts? If so will the accepted tick be applied to the highest scoring out of the winning person's posts?

Comment: @trichoplax the overall winner with the highest score summed up over all of their answer posts will receive the tick on their highest scored post. It doesn't really matter which post in particular (as long as it is a post of the winner) receives the tick, but it makes sense to tick off the highest scoring post.

Comment: Well, it's up to you about the dupe issue. I won't hammer it close by myself, but other users might close it.

Comment: Ok, if anyone else seems to agree that it is too similar, than we can work from there and I can delete or voluntarily close it myself.

Comment: @xnor ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ forgot to ping

Comment: If you decide it's not a duplicate then I think it's worth putting a short, clear summary of the difference in scoring near the top of the post to minimise close votes based on misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok on it @trichoplax

Answer (score 0):

## Play the centipede game

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

*(please note that I need to learn how to make a controller)*

In this challenge, you must create a bot which plays the centipede game.

In the centipede game, there are two players, and two piles of coins. One pile is 1/4 the size of the other. Each turn, a player may choose to either: a) take the bigger pile of coins for himself, and push the smaller pile of coins over to the other player, or b) push both piles of coins to the other player. When the coins are pushed to the other player, the size of each of the pile of coins is doubled (in this way, the smaller pile increases to the current size of the big pile after two pushes).

In the original centipede game, there were 100 rounds (hence the name). However, in this game, there will be a random number of rounds. If the game ends without anyone defecting, the big pile will be evenly split between the bots.

The game is over when someone takes the pile instead of pushing it over, or the random amount of rounds are elapsed

I'm currently not entirely sure how to score it, but I know that a bot definitely cannot benefit from deliberately messing up the opponent (as in, it can't try to drag another players score down with it, even if that wouldn't be effective), other than the score it gains. something like `Average score-(average score of games by other bots that weren't against the bot being scored)`, if that scoring method is not the inverse of what I'm trying to accomplish, but something formatted like that

Comment: It seems to me that there are two key factors which affect the analysis: do I know how many (half-)turns have already passed? And do I know how many (half-)turns are still to come? If the answer to the second is no, you should at least state the probability distribution. (We can extract it anyway from the controller, but it shouldn't be necessary to reverse engineer key details from the controller).

Answer (score 0):

## What number is this in the lowest possible base?

The challenge ["What base is this number in"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90711/what-base-is-this-number-in) has an obvious extension:

> Given a string that represents a number in an unknown base, determine the lowest possible base that number might be in, *and taking the number in that base, output its base-10 representation*. The string will only contain `0-9, a-z`. If you like, you may choose to take uppercase letters instead of lowercase, but please specify this.

So, for example, if the input string is "01234", then the lowest possible base it could be a number in is 5. And in base-5, it represents:

```
01234_5 = 0 × 5^4 + 1 × 5^3 + 2 × 5^2 + 3 × 5^1 + 4 × 5^0 = (125 + 50 + 15 + 4)_10 = 194_10
```

So your program should output "194".

Your code must also work for base-1, aka "unary", where a number is represented by a string of zeros and its value is the number of digits. For example, `00000_1 = 5_10`.

You can expect valid output to be anywhere from `0` to `max_int`.

You may take input and provide output in any reasonable format. Base-conversion built-ins are allowed (Sandbox q: Should there maybe be a bonus for not using them?), shortest answer in bytes is the winner!

### Sample results:

```
    Input  | Base | Output
     1001  | 2    | 9
     34f9  | 16   | 13561
  0000000  | 1    | 7
  0000001  | 2    | 1
 codegolf  | 25   | 79234249915
```

#### Super-long example:

```
Input: 0123456789abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Base: 36
Output (spaces for legibility, not required in actual program): 86 846 823 611 197 163 108 337 531 226 495 015 298 096 208 677 436 155
```

This output is roughly 180 bits, or 22.5 bytes, so may be out of range, but if your program can manage it then well done!

You may want to use [baseconvert.com](http://baseconvert.com) to help check your results.

Comment: I really don't get how 0000000 is 7 in base 1.

Comment: In unary, rather than doing proper base calculations, you use each digit as a tally. So you just count how many 0s there are. Technically, you'd normally use 1111111 with a subscript 1, but since in this challenge 1111111 would be read as a binary number, I'm using the alternative definition.

Comment: That's rather odd. Unary is a bijective numeration, so it doesn't even have zeroes. Personally, I'd just stike 1 from the possible bases.

Comment: @Dennis, I think the point of including unary is that it's the only thing which stops the question being an exact duplicate. As it is, I think it's a close enough duplicate to close.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48952/minimum-base-to-count-to-a-string

Comment: I searched for lowest base, and not minimum base. That's my fault and I'm fine with closing.

Answer (score 0):

### Strict Music Interval Describer

Given two notes, you might think you can combine [Print the sizes of intervals inside of a piece of music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/print-the-sizes-of-intervals-inside-of-a-piece-of-music) to give you the number of semitones with [Music Interval Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76120/music-interval-solver) to give you the name of the interval between them. Unfortunately doing this loses information. You might notice from the Music Interval Solver that different intervals can have the same number of semitones. In order to know which interval we should use, we need to refer back to the original note names.

The base name of an interval can always be determined from the inclusive number of note names, excluding accidentals, from the first note to the second. Note that intervals wrap after the octave, so that G# to C# is a fourth (G, A, B, C). For this question the octave numbers are not provided so you should assume that the interval will always be an ascending interval between a second and an octave.

To avoid having to refer to the linked questions, I will remind you that the notes themselves have differing numbers of semitones between them; E & F and B & C have one while the others have two. G to C is therefore 2 + 2 + 1 = 5 semitones.

You also need to take into account the accidentals; we'll use # and b for simplicity. They each alter the interval by 1 semitone; # increases it if used on the second note while b increases it if used on the first note. Naturally if both notes have the same accidental then they will cancel out.

An interval also has a modifier. My fourth above was in fact a perfect fourth, because the number of semitones was 5; the other possible perfect interval is a perfect fifth, which is 7 semitones. You can choose whether to use octave or perfect octave for 12 semitones.

Seconds, thirds, sixths and sevenths have minor and major intervals. The major intervals are 2, 4, 9 and 11 semitones; the minor intervals have one fewer.

Unlike the Music Interval Solver, if your interval does not match any of the intervals so far, you cannot simply change to a different base interval. Instead, you must augment or diminish your interval. For the purposes of this question any interval smaller than a minor or perfect interval is a diminished interval, and any interval larger than a major or perfect interval is an augmented interval.

Test cases:

```
Eb F# - augmented second
C# Eb - diminished third
G# C# - perfect fourth
F B - augmented fourth
B F - diminished fifth
Db B# - augmented sixth
A# Gb - diminished seventh
C# C - diminished octave
```

Input/output can be in any reasonable format (e.g. one string with a space separator, an array of two strings). This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: 1. The first sentence seems backwards to me: surely the issue you're disagreeing with is the input, not the output, so why "*providing*"? 2. If I understand this correctly, you want to take two notes as input, map to the separation between them, and then pass that through to the earlier question. In other words, it seems to be http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5410/194 + http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76120/194 . I think that makes it a dupe.

Comment: No, the note names are highly relevant. It is wrong to describe an interval of F to B as a diminished fifth or B to F as an augmented fourth.

Comment: When you say, "*No,*" with what precisely are you disagreeing?

Comment: I'm disagreeing with your comment part 2.

Comment: So are you saying that 5410 is badly specified? Or something else?

Comment: It only required you to output a possible name of the interval, given that you had incomplete information. Maybe it was deliberately specified like that because it allowed simpler input requirements.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross-purposes. 5410 (linked in my first comment) is: given two notes, how many semitones is it from the first to the second. Then 76120, which you also linked in the question, is: given the distance in semitones, what's the name of the interval. The combination of the two seems to me to be: given two notes, what is the name of the interval between them.

Comment: No, because you lose data; 5410 will output 6 semitones for both F to B and B to F, and then 76120 doesn't know whether that's an augmented fourth or a diminished fifth.

Comment: Having read this question several times, neither do I, so maybe if you improve the specification the difference will become apparent.

Comment: I don't know a clearer way of putting it than the inclusive number of note names. F to B is a fourth because there are four letters F, G, A, B. B to F is a fifth because there are five letters B, C, D, E, f.

Comment: I think what Neil's getting at is that modified intervals should be expressed relative to the note with the same letter name as the second input in the major scale corresponding to the first input? But it's not specified what should happen if two or three sharps/flats need to be applied to get from the scale note to the second input. Also, two of the test cases are inaccurate: C#-Eb is a second, and Db-B# is a major seventh.

Comment: @feersum C to E is three notes, not two, and D to B is six notes, not seven.

Comment: @feersum No, that's a minor third.

Comment: All right, I see that diminished third is actually a standard term. But it seems to conflict with the rule saying *If your interval does not match any of the ones so far...* since the interval does match one of the ones listed above.

Comment: @feersum I've rephrased my question a bit, does that help?

Comment: Yes. A test case with a difference of 3 would be good like `G# Fb`.

Comment: @feersum Difference of 3 what? Your example was 7 notes or 8 semitones. I added an example for 3 semitones.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it is diminished by 3 semitones from the major seventh.

Comment: This question still doesn't seem clearly specified to me, and certainly isn't self-contained. I am coming to the conclusion that the best way to specify the answer for all possible inputs would be a table of all 18*18 = 324 possible inputs and their corresponding outputs. I think it would just fit in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: 441 possible inputs: (7 notes, 2 optional accidentals) twice.

Comment: If `Fb B#` is a possible input then that certainly wasn't clear to me!

Answer (score 0):

## How can I get To a RepDigit Rep?

Heavily inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90892/how-can-i-get-a-repdigit)

In the referenced challenge, Repdigits are defined as numbers composed of repeating single digits (1, 111, 88, 99999, etc). In this challenge, we will calculate the minimum number of Stack Exchange Q/A votes it takes to take a reputation to a repdigit.

A vote can either be:

- Question upvote (+5)
- Answer upvote (+10)
- Question/Answer downvote (-2)

**Input**:
A single positive integer which represents a Stack Exchange reputation

**Output**: The minimum number of votes required to reach the nearest repdigit

**Rules:**

- Answer may be either program or function
- Input may be user input, read from a file, or function argument
- Output may have trialing spaces/new lines and should be printed/displayed to STDOUT or nearest equivalent.  Alternatively, output may be the return value of a function
- Standard loopholes apply
- Answers should work theoretically for infinite reputation, however for practicality, answers only need to work up to 889,107 reputation (Jon Skeet's SO rep at time of posting)

**Test Cases**:

```
Reputation: 1   =>  Votes: 0 (input is already a repdigit)
Reputation: 10  =>  Votes: 1 (one downvote will result in 8 rep)
Reputation: 500 =>  Votes: 6 (5 answer upvotes and 1 question upvote resulting in 555 rep)
```

This is codegolf, shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: What is the largest and smallest possible inputs as rep.

Comment: Minimum of 1, maximum of 889,109

Comment: Totally irrelevant but just out of curiosity: Will the figure shown for Jon Skeet's rep be updated with the current figure when this gets posted to main?

Comment: @trichoplax, yeah, of course, its attention to detail that makes a good challenge!

Answer (score 0):

## Origami in One Dimension

[subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[repeated-transformation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-transformation)

In this restricted version of origami, the artist begins with an unfolded strip of paper `n` segments long, the segments labeled from `0` on the left up through `n - 1` on the right.  For instance, if `n` were 7, the unfolded strip of paper would look like this:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

Then the artist repeatedly makes "mountain" folds, each time tucking the right side under the left, based on a sequence of crease locations `S`.  These locations are given as integer distances from the paper's left edge.

For example, consider the sequence `[3, 3, 0, 3]`.  According to it, the first crease in the paper above should be made three units from the left edge, so segments `3` through `6`, to the right of the crease, would get tucked beneath `0` through `2` to the crease's left:

```
    | 0 | 1 | 2 \
| 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 /
```

The second crease is to be three units from the new left edge, so that fold would tuck the `2` and `3` under everything else:

```
    | 0 | 1  \
| 6 | 5 | 4 \ |
        / 3 / |
        \ 2  /
```

The third crease should fall zero units from the left edge, meaning that the entire paper is to its right, and the whole thing gets flipped over:

```
 /  2 \
| / 3 /
| \ 4 | 5 | 6 |
 \  1 | 0 |
```

And finally, the fourth fold falls on the paper's right edge, flipping nothing.

Thus, the completed artwork, when viewed from above, would read `[2, 5, 6]`.

Write a program or function that, given the nonnegative integer `n` and a sequence of crease locations `S`, returns the sequence of integers visible on the final folded paper as seen from above.  You may assume that all of the elements of `S` are in-bounds, though creases are allowed to fall on edges as above.  Some randomly generated sample inputs and outputs:

```
0,  []                       -> []
1,  [1]                      -> [0]
2,  [0]                      -> [1, 0]
2,  [1, 0, 1]                -> [1]
3,  [0, 2]                   -> [2, 1]
3,  [3, 2]                   -> [0, 1]
3,  [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]       -> [1, 0]
4,  [1, 1]                   -> [1, 3]
4,  [2, 2]                   -> [0, 1]
4,  [4, 2, 2, 0]             -> [2, 3]
5,  [3, 2]                   -> [0, 1]
5,  [3, 0, 0]                -> [0, 1, 2]
5,  [5, 0, 1]                -> [0, 1, 2, 4]
6,  [2]                      -> [5, 4, 0, 1]
6,  [5, 0]                   -> [5, 3, 2, 1, 0]
6,  [6, 1, 1]                -> [1, 2, 3, 5]
6,  [0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2]    -> [1, 5]
7,  [6, 1, 2]                -> [1, 6, 4]
7,  [3, 3, 0, 3]             -> [2, 5, 6]
7,  [7, 2, 0, 0]             -> [6, 5, 4, 0, 1]
7,  [3, 0, 0, 1, 2]          -> [3, 4]
8,  [3, 1]                   -> [3, 4, 5, 7]
8,  [3, 2, 3]                -> [3, 7, 6]
9,  []                       -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
9,  [2, 1]                   -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
9,  [5, 1]                   -> [5, 6, 7, 0]
9,  [8, 4, 2, 0, 0]          -> [0, 1]
10, [3, 2]                   -> [3, 4, 5, 9, 8]
10, [0, 5, 5]                -> [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
10, [0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0] -> [4, 3, 2]
```

Rules and scoring are as usual for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Remaining Sandbox Questions

In addition to general feedback, I'd appreciate an input on:

- Is the revised specification clear?
- Is the barrier to getting started on this challenge low enough?
- Is there sufficient room here for a variety of approaches?

Comment: Very neat challenge, but I think you should clarify some edge cases: 1) if the fold is done at `0`, does that just rotate the entire paper 180 degrees? 2) Will the paper ever be folded onto other layers, e.g. at the end of your example, could there be a `1`, and if so would the `2` go below the `0`? 3) Will a fold ever affect multiple layers, e.g. `8, [4, 2]` and if so are they folded individually or all together? I assume you've covered these in your test cases, but it would be great to see them in the worked example, so people don't have to reverse engineer these details from the test cases.

Comment: As for tags, I'd probably drop [tag:sequence]. It's usually used for OEIS-like integer sequences, and you seem to be using it to refer to lists, which is covered by [tag:array-manipulation].

Comment: Revised per comments.

Answer (score 0):

## Limit a table

(this is in minimal form, and is in rough sandbox stage. refrain from voting at this stage. I will flesh it out at a later point in time.)

Given a CSV file containing two columns, and an integer N, format the table into multiple rows such that each column contains at most N rows, excluding the header. Like this, for N = 3:

```
Foo,Bar
hello,world
lorem,ipsum
doler,illum
asdf,fdasfa
qwerty,dvorak
tildes,graves
stuff,hello
limit,ipsum
a,b
```

Becomes:

```
Foo,Bar,Foo,Bar,Foo,Bar
hello,world,asdf,fdasfa,stuff,hello
lorem,ipsum,qwerty,dvorak,limit,ipsum
doler,illum,tildes,graves,a,b
```

Comment: I think I understand how the output is constructed from the input, but this is basically not explained in the challenge which makes it extremely unclear.

Comment: @Fatalize of course. "this is in minimal form, and is in rough sandbox stage."

Answer (score 0):

### Tower of Hanoi Hamiltonian Cycle

Every tower of Hanoi has a unique Hamiltonian cycle of length 3ⁿ. The cycle for `n=1` is simply `1| | , |1| , | |1` while for `n=2` it is as follows:

```
12          move disc 1 from rod 1 to rod 2
2   1                 2          1        3
    1   2             1          2        3
        12            1          3        1
1       2             2          3        2
1   2                 1          1        2
    12                1          2        3
    2   1             2          2        1
2       1             1          3        1 - closes cycle
```

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a positive integer `n`, returns the Hamiltonian cycle for the Hanoi Graph of order `n`.

You can output the graph starting at any point and traversing it in either order. You can output the graph as a list of positions or a list of moves. It must be possible to loop back from the last line of your output to the first, but you don't have to repeat the position.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: The cycle can be constructed as a trivial variant of [solving the standard tower of Hanoi puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5790/194), making this a duplicate.

Comment: The standard solution is simply a straight line along the edge of the Hanoi graph, while the cycle is a fractal. How is that a trivial variant?

Answer (score 0):

## Warn me when charger is unplugged!

So, I've a [Compaq Presario V6000](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/compaq-presario-v6000-notebook-pc-series/1842076) laptop. Two years ago, battery died because of overcharging; So I had to plug charger in order to work with. Without the charger plugged, it runs out of power after ~4 seconds. Unfortunately, today I found out that charger port is tighten because of intense use & charger gets unplugged after few minutes. Your task is to solve my problem by writing a full program which warns me about unplugged charger!

## GOAL

- Write a full program that opens an X windows or makes similar graphical drawing that warns me about unplugged charger with writing "WARNING" in a readable font with size 36 and in color red.
- Your program must warn me in less than 2 seconds after being unplugged.
- Information about my laptop is available [HERE](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/compaq-presario-v6000-notebook-pc-series/1842076). It's running Slacko puppy 6.3.0 with JWM & other default programs.

Here's what I've in /dev directory :

```
adsp
agpgart
audio
audio1
autofs
bsg
btrfs-control
bus
cdrom
char
console
cpu_dma_latency
cuse
dac960_gam
dri
dsp
dsp1
dvd
fb0
fd
full
fuse
hidraw0
hpet
hwrng
input
kmsg
log
loop0
loop1
loop10
loop11
loop12
loop13
loop14
loop15
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
loop8
loop9
loop-control
mapper
mcelog
md0
mem
mixer
mixer1
mouse
mptctl
nbd0
nbd1
nbd10
nbd11
nbd12
nbd13
nbd14
nbd15
nbd2
nbd3
nbd4
nbd5
nbd6
nbd7
nbd8
nbd9
net
network_latency
network_throughput
null
port
ppp
psaux
ptmx
pts
ptya0
ptya1
ptya2
ptya3
ptya4
ptya5
ptya6
ptya7
ptya8
ptya9
ptyaa
ptyab
ptyac
ptyad
ptyae
ptyaf
ptyb0
ptyb1
ptyb2
ptyb3
ptyb4
ptyb5
ptyb6
ptyb7
ptyb8
ptyb9
ptyba
ptybb
ptybc
ptybd
ptybe
ptybf
ptyc0
ptyc1
ptyc2
ptyc3
ptyc4
ptyc5
ptyc6
ptyc7
ptyc8
ptyc9
ptyca
ptycb
ptycc
ptycd
ptyce
ptycf
ptyd0
ptyd1
ptyd2
ptyd3
ptyd4
ptyd5
ptyd6
ptyd7
ptyd8
ptyd9
ptyda
ptydb
ptydc
ptydd
ptyde
ptydf
ptye0
ptye1
ptye2
ptye3
ptye4
ptye5
ptye6
ptye7
ptye8
ptye9
ptyea
ptyeb
ptyec
ptyed
ptyee
ptyef
ptyp0
ptyp1
ptyp2
ptyp3
ptyp4
ptyp5
ptyp6
ptyp7
ptyp8
ptyp9
ptypa
ptypb
ptypc
ptypd
ptype
ptypf
ptyq0
ptyq1
ptyq2
ptyq3
ptyq4
ptyq5
ptyq6
ptyq7
ptyq8
ptyq9
ptyqa
ptyqb
ptyqc
ptyqd
ptyqe
ptyqf
ptyr0
ptyr1
ptyr2
ptyr3
ptyr4
ptyr5
ptyr6
ptyr7
ptyr8
ptyr9
ptyra
ptyrb
ptyrc
ptyrd
ptyre
ptyrf
ptys0
ptys1
ptys2
ptys3
ptys4
ptys5
ptys6
ptys7
ptys8
ptys9
ptysa
ptysb
ptysc
ptysd
ptyse
ptysf
ptyt0
ptyt1
ptyt2
ptyt3
ptyt4
ptyt5
ptyt6
ptyt7
ptyt8
ptyt9
ptyta
ptytb
ptytc
ptytd
ptyte
ptytf
ptyu0
ptyu1
ptyu2
ptyu3
ptyu4
ptyu5
ptyu6
ptyu7
ptyu8
ptyu9
ptyua
ptyub
ptyuc
ptyud
ptyue
ptyuf
ptyv0
ptyv1
ptyv2
ptyv3
ptyv4
ptyv5
ptyv6
ptyv7
ptyv8
ptyv9
ptyva
ptyvb
ptyvc
ptyvd
ptyve
ptyvf
ptyw0
ptyw1
ptyw2
ptyw3
ptyw4
ptyw5
ptyw6
ptyw7
ptyw8
ptyw9
ptywa
ptywb
ptywc
ptywd
ptywe
ptywf
ptyx0
ptyx1
ptyx2
ptyx3
ptyx4
ptyx5
ptyx6
ptyx7
ptyx8
ptyx9
ptyxa
ptyxb
ptyxc
ptyxd
ptyxe
ptyxf
ptyy0
ptyy1
ptyy2
ptyy3
ptyy4
ptyy5
ptyy6
ptyy7
ptyy8
ptyy9
ptyya
ptyyb
ptyyc
ptyyd
ptyye
ptyyf
ptyz0
ptyz1
ptyz2
ptyz3
ptyz4
ptyz5
ptyz6
ptyz7
ptyz8
ptyz9
ptyza
ptyzb
ptyzc
ptyzd
ptyze
ptyzf
ram0
ram1
ram10
ram11
ram12
ram13
ram14
ram15
ram2
ram3
ram4
ram5
ram6
ram7
ram8
ram9
random
rfkill
rtc0
sda
sda1
sda2
sequencer
sequencer2
shm
snd
sr0
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
tty0
tty1
tty10
tty11
tty12
tty13
tty14
tty15
tty16
tty17
tty18
tty19
tty2
tty20
tty21
tty22
tty23
tty24
tty25
tty26
tty27
tty28
tty29
tty3
tty30
tty31
tty32
tty33
tty34
tty35
tty36
tty37
tty38
tty39
tty4
tty40
tty41
tty42
tty43
tty44
tty45
tty46
tty47
tty48
tty49
tty5
tty50
tty51
tty52
tty53
tty54
tty55
tty56
tty57
tty58
tty59
tty6
tty60
tty61
tty62
tty63
tty7
tty8
tty9
ttya0
ttya1
ttya2
ttya3
ttya4
ttya5
ttya6
ttya7
ttya8
ttya9
ttyaa
ttyab
ttyac
ttyad
ttyae
ttyaf
ttyb0
ttyb1
ttyb2
ttyb3
ttyb4
ttyb5
ttyb6
ttyb7
ttyb8
ttyb9
ttyba
ttybb
ttybc
ttybd
ttybe
ttybf
ttyc0
ttyc1
ttyc2
ttyc3
ttyc4
ttyc5
ttyc6
ttyc7
ttyc8
ttyc9
ttyca
ttycb
ttycc
ttycd
ttyce
ttycf
ttyd0
ttyd1
ttyd2
ttyd3
ttyd4
ttyd5
ttyd6
ttyd7
ttyd8
ttyd9
ttyda
ttydb
ttydc
ttydd
ttyde
ttydf
ttye0
ttye1
ttye2
ttye3
ttye4
ttye5
ttye6
ttye7
ttye8
ttye9
ttyea
ttyeb
ttyec
ttyed
ttyee
ttyef
ttyp0
ttyp1
ttyp2
ttyp3
ttyp4
ttyp5
ttyp6
ttyp7
ttyp8
ttyp9
ttypa
ttypb
ttypc
ttypd
ttype
ttypf
ttyq0
ttyq1
ttyq2
ttyq3
ttyq4
ttyq5
ttyq6
ttyq7
ttyq8
ttyq9
ttyqa
ttyqb
ttyqc
ttyqd
ttyqe
ttyqf
ttyr0
ttyr1
ttyr2
ttyr3
ttyr4
ttyr5
ttyr6
ttyr7
ttyr8
ttyr9
ttyra
ttyrb
ttyrc
ttyrd
ttyre
ttyrf
ttys0
ttyS0
ttys1
ttyS1
ttys2
ttyS2
ttys3
ttyS3
ttys4
ttys5
ttys6
ttys7
ttys8
ttys9
ttysa
ttysb
ttysc
ttysd
ttyse
ttysf
ttyt0
ttyt1
ttyt2
ttyt3
ttyt4
ttyt5
ttyt6
ttyt7
ttyt8
ttyt9
ttyta
ttytb
ttytc
ttytd
ttyte
ttytf
ttyu0
ttyu1
ttyu2
ttyu3
ttyu4
ttyu5
ttyu6
ttyu7
ttyu8
ttyu9
ttyua
ttyub
ttyuc
ttyud
ttyue
ttyuf
ttyv0
ttyv1
ttyv2
ttyv3
ttyv4
ttyv5
ttyv6
ttyv7
ttyv8
ttyv9
ttyva
ttyvb
ttyvc
ttyvd
ttyve
ttyvf
ttyw0
ttyw1
ttyw2
ttyw3
ttyw4
ttyw5
ttyw6
ttyw7
ttyw8
ttyw9
ttywa
ttywb
ttywc
ttywd
ttywe
ttywf
ttyx0
ttyx1
ttyx2
ttyx3
ttyx4
ttyx5
ttyx6
ttyx7
ttyx8
ttyx9
ttyxa
ttyxb
ttyxc
ttyxd
ttyxe
ttyxf
ttyy0
ttyy1
ttyy2
ttyy3
ttyy4
ttyy5
ttyy6
ttyy7
ttyy8
ttyy9
ttyya
ttyyb
ttyyc
ttyyd
ttyye
ttyyf
ttyz0
ttyz1
ttyz2
ttyz3
ttyz4
ttyz5
ttyz6
ttyz7
ttyz8
ttyz9
ttyza
ttyzb
ttyzc
ttyzd
ttyze
ttyzf
uhid
uinput
urandom
vcs
vcs1
vcs2
vcs3
vcs4
vcs5
vcsa
vcsa1
vcsa2
vcsa3
vcsa4
vcsa5
vga_arbiter
vhost-net
zero
```

Here's what I've in /etc directory

```
acpi                      hostname               pavrecord
adjtime                   hosts                  pcmcia
asound.state              hosts.allow            pkcs11
at-spi2                   hosts.deny             ppp
bash_completion.d         init.d                 precord
belocs                    inittab                printcap
ca-certificates           inputrc                profile
ca-certificates.conf      issue                  profile.d
ca-certificates.conf.new  jwm-2.3.xslt           protocols
cdburnerdevice            kde                    Puppybackgroundpicture
clock                     keymap                 radiusclient
codepage                  keymap_previous        ramdiskfssize
cron.daily                lazarus                ramdisksize
cups                      ld.so.cache            rc.d
dbus-1                    ld.so.conf             rc_keymaps
default                   ld.so.conf.d           rc_maps.cfg
desktop_icon_theme        libnl                  README.txt
dhcpcd.conf               localtime              request-key.conf
dhcpcd.conf.new           localtime-copied-from  request-key.d
dhcpcd.duid               logrotate.d            resolutionfix
dhcpcd_state_notify       lvm                    resolv.conf
dhcpcd_state_notify.bak   lynx.cfg               rpc
dict.conf                 lynx.lss               samba
dictd.conf                mailcap                sane.d
DISTRO_SPECS              mc                     securetelnetrc
drirc                     mime.types             services
esd.conf                  misc                   shadow
esd.conf.new              mke2fs.conf            shadow-
eventmanager              mke2fs.conf.new        shells
fb.modes                  modprobe.d             simple_network_setup
fdprm                     modules                slsh.rc
file                      modules.conf           ssl
floppy                    mousebuttons           sudo.conf
fltk                      mousedevice            sudoers
fontmap                   mtab                   sudoers.d
fonts                     my.cnf                 system.jwmrc
foomatic                  my.cnf.d               udev
fpc.cfg                   mysqlaccess.conf       uniconf.conf
fppkg                     nanorc                 usb_modeswitch.conf
fppkg.cfg                 nanorc.new             usb_modeswitch.d
frisbee                   NETWORKING             vga
fstab                     networkmodules         wcpufreqdriver
fstab.bak                 networks               wgetrc
gamin                     network-wizard         windowmanager
gconf                     nscd.conf              wpa_supplicant.conf
gftp                      nscd.conf.new          wpa_supplicant.conf.new
group                     nsswitch.conf          wvdial.conf
group-                    oldmousedevice         wvdial_options
gshadow                   openldap               X11
gshadow-                  os-release             xdg
gtk-2.0                   pam.d                  xextraoptions
gtk-3.0                   pango                  xorgoverrides
hiawatha                  passwd
host.conf                 passwd-
```

- Your program must not hurt my friend in any way

This is a [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf). Shortest codes win!

Comment: This is an interesting one. However, the obvious problem is the fact that is it must be always running as a process, so an interpreted programming language will have problems, am I right?

Comment: To other users: I think that the amount of information dumped into the the code areas could be greatly reduced by omitting such irrelevant things as `sudoers`, for example. Another think is making this challenge “do X for me”, maybe by reformulating the task.

Comment: Oh, and how are we supposed to test our code if we do not have this notebook model? Maybe this challenge should be more general?

Answer (score 0):

## The number 3 is cursed; avoid it

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sub>Inspired from [this](https://xkcd.com/1275/)</sub>

It's well know that the number 3 may lead to weird bugs in a program. So your task is to write a program to remove every literal `3` (only the base 10 number; not a `3` in a string, a variable name, a longer number or with a different base) in a source code written in the language of your program by the floor of π.

But you can't have the character `3` anywhere in your source code.

You can't use a language without number literals.

#### Test cases (source language: Python)

```
print(3)
=>
import math
print(int(math.pi))
```

```
print("3 * 1 = %d" % 3)
=>
import math
print("3 * 1 = %d" % int(math.pi))
```

```
var1 = var2 = 33
var3 = 3 * var1 + var2 * 3
print("3 * %d + %d * 3 = %d" % var3)
=>
import math
var1 = var2 = 33
var3 = int(math.pi) * var1 + var2 * int(math.pi)
print("3 * %d + %d = %d" % var3)
```

```
print(0x3)
=>
print(0x3)
```

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes win. Good luck!

Comment: So the empty brainfuck program wins?

Comment: **1.** There isn't a clear definition of esolang. Also, it makes no sense to disallow a huge number of programming languages, just because a small subset of them trivializes the problem. **2.** What about `0x3`, `0o3` or `0b11` in Python? Those are also numeric literals that represent 3. **3.** What is the language in question doesn't have a built-in for Pi? **4.** What counts as *flooring*? Python's `int` doesn't floor, although it happens to work that way for pi.

Comment: Why is there a language restriction at all?

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ To prevent 0-byte brainfuck answer

Comment: Should the resulting program run/compile? For example, the Haskell code `3 + 1.0` works, but `floor pi + 1.0` gives a type error. Can we add additional code to fix such things (-> `fromInteger (floor pi) + 1.0`)?

Comment: @nimi Yes you can

Comment: I guess, the resulting program should run/compile and do exactly the same as the original program (maybe you should note this explicitly). There are far more exceptions where a replacement will fail than in your list (not a string, not a variable name, etc). Examples are Basic's line numbers or Perl's `format` which has literal text without being a string. I doubt one can name them all. You can argue that not all languages are suited for this task, but then why make exceptions at all?

Answer (score 0):

## Simulate World's smallest universal Turing machine

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

---

### Goal:

to implement world smallest automata which was proved (though, not strictly) to be able to simulate any other universal Turing machine, Wolfram's 2-state 3-symbol Turing machine & prove your language's Turing-completeness.

[image]

### Specification:

> {{1, 2} -> {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1} -> {1, 2, -1}, {1, 0} -> {2, 1, 1}, 
>   {2, 2} -> {1, 0, 1}, {2, 1} -> {2, 2, 1}, {2, 0} -> {1, 2, -1}}
>
> where this means {state, color} -> {state, color, offset}. (Colors of cells on the tape are sometimes instead thought of as "symbols" written to the tape.)
>   [Source](http://www.wolframscience.com/prizes/tm23/technicaldetails.html)

#### "Word" description:

Think of this machine as an array processing function. This array has a pointer accessible by function. Every cell in this array can store an integer from 0 upto 2. Array is infinite from both sides & pointer is pointing to somewhere in the middle of this array. function itself has 2 modes. in each mode, it works different than other. Let's call these 2 modes "A" & "B".

if in state "A" :

- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 0, change it to 1 & increase pointer & toggle state;
- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 1, change it to 2 & decrease pointer;
- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 2, change it to 1 & decrease pointer;

if in state "B" :

- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 0, change it to 2 & decrease pointer & toggle state;
- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 1, change it to 2 & increase pointer;
- if the value of the cell pointed by pointer is 2, change it to 0 & increase pointer & toggle state;

(Increasing the pointer moves it to right.)

Your program's array must be at least (2^16+1) and when it goes out of boundary, pointer must come back from other side. Size of array must be either dynamic or odd (Which at first, pointer is pointing to middle element of array).

### I/O format

Though there aren't strict rules about input & output. Your program must at least get number of iterations as an input & output current pointer address (an integer, 0 at first, negetive if pointer gets decremented to subzero) & value of pointed cell along with a seprator (e.g. space) at every iteration. Though this is the minimal requirement.

### Winning criteria(s)

There aren't many restrictions about challenge itself. But for wining, you'll need to get other users' votes. You can try to make an optimized system, or simulate it in a strange language, or have an strange design. But you mustn't add anything extra to machine itself, and must be able to produce the exact state of pointer and tape in a particular iteration.

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). Answers with highest votes will win.

Comment: This looks like a "*be creative*" popcon, which [should be avoided](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info). Why popcon rather than an objective winning criterion?

Answer (score 0):

## Output a number tent

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

---

Given an integer, output a number tent. (The number tent is just called as such.)

The input determines:

- whether the tent is upside down (negative) or right way up (positive),
- whether the entrance is on the left side (even) or the right side (odd), and
- the size of the tent ([abs(input/2) http://mathurl.com/hwkkw3f.png](http://mathurl.com/hwkkw3f.png) with integer division).

---

```
For input -4:
________
\  /   /
 \/___/
```

Assume that the input will never be `1`, `0` or `-1`.

> **TODO** Clarify.

Your code should be as short as possible.

Comment: Input of `1` should return an empty string (as should `-1` and, of course, `0`, although we should clarify that size is `abs(input/2)` with integer division). Tag suggestion: ascii-art

Answer (score 0):

## Output a confusion matrix

[A confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is a pretty typical thing to see in a machine learning paper. It is a matrix where each cell contains the number of instances of the class of the row that were classified as the class of the column.

For example, if we have two classes `A` and `B`, and 4 instances `[A, A]` (meaning that instance is of class `A` and was classified as `A`), `[A, B]`, `[B, B]` and `[B, B]`, then the resulting confusion matrix would be:

```
  A B
A 1 1
B   2
```

---

TODO: more details about the format, what happens if the name of the classes have different lengths, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Find all paths in a matrix maze.**

A maze is represented as a two-dimensional array of 0s and 1s. Zero indicates a closed door and one indicates an open door. An example representation of maze is given below.

```
0100
0010
1101
```

to avoid loops input square matrix should not contain a square of once like

```
111      11
101  or  11
111
```

Write an application either in Java,C,C++,Python,C# or Javascript. It takes as input a maze(mxn array) and prints out all the possible ways out.

• No database should be used.

• Yes...Way out is any edge containing 1.

• Enter from any edges of the maze

• Exit from any edges of the maze

• Should not enter and exit from the same door

• Move can be one unit distance either top/bottom/left/right/diagonal

For the above maze, one possible way out is: `[0,1] -> [1,2] -> [2,3]` i.e you start at `[0,1]` and then move to `[1,2]` and then to `[2,3]`. There are other possible ways as you can see.

Comment: Probable dupes: [One](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/586/robot-finds-kitten), [Two](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44513/find-the-straightest-path-in-a-maze)

Comment: Also, restricting challenges to specific languages are frowned upon. An objective winning criterion is also needed.

Comment: @Emigna, No Actually, here we need to find all the paths not the shortest path or straight path and here we can also traverse diagonal in the matrix.

Comment: okay will add few more languages that I know so that I can evaluate ...

Comment: 1. "*Handle error cases like a production application*" is not a clear requirement. Different production applications have different standards for how to handle errors. 2. "*prints out all the possible ways out*" runs into trouble when there's an infinite number, and I don't see any guarantee that there won't be loops. 3. The example doesn't make the input format very clear. What's the non-rectangular border for? 4. Path-finding with a trivial input format is definitely a dupe of at least one previous question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I have modified my question, can you plz check once.

Answer (score 0):

## Auto golf a string

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)

Your objective is to make a program (written in a language of your choice) that takes arbitrary strings as input and outputs a program in a constant target language that, when run, prints that string. The original program does not have to be golfed, but the output programs should be in some way optimal or nearly optimal.

Voters are encouraged to keep the following points in mind when voting:

1. How difficult is the target language to program in? Is it on par with languages such as [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and [whitespace](http://web.archive.org/web/20150623025348/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/), or is it something trivial, like Python or Ruby?
2. How efficient is the golfer? That is, how does it compare to any existent auto string golfers? And how does it compare to hand-golfing?

---

### Meta

Okay, so this isn't our usual type of challenge, but I think this could really turn out well. However, I think this is underspecified as it is, and would appreciate feedback.

Comment: This may overlap with some other metagolfing questions... That will mean that any future kolmo meta-golfing qs will be dupes.

Comment: @BetaDecay Yeah, but only in reference to strings

Comment: This is a bad fit for a site with a 30000 character limit to answers. I would have to golf 12kB off my GolfScript-Kolmogorov program to fit it in an answer even *without* any explanation beyond the comments in the code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that is certainly impressive. How substantial are the reductions?

Comment: See e.g. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42400/194 , http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11568/194 . Also [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59261/194).

Answer (score 0):

## Balanced use of the alphabet

Write a program that counts from 1 to 100 and back down and ends by the sentence "I finished counting":

`1, 2, 3, ... 97, 98, 99, 100, 99, 98, 97, ... 3, 2, 1, I finished counting`

The output can be of any kind: array, comma separated, line separated, ...

In order to do that, your code reviewer (who has a wierd OCD) won't accept code that doesn't contain the same amount of each letters of the alphabet.

He also doesn't accept code with no letter at all because, you know... letters are cool.

### Scoring

Your score will be `codeLength * (mostRepresentedLetter / leastRepresentedLetter)`.

### Example of scoring

(Bad) code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz();}
```

Length: 39
Most represented letter: i (5 times)
Least represented letter: a (once)
Score: 39 * 5 / 1 = **195**

NOTE: if a letter is not at all present, divding something by zero will make an inifinite score. As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), it is not something you want.

Comment: As written, what prevents folks from just putting any extraneous letters behind a comment? How would code that doesn't use ASCII, like APL or Jelly, be scored?

Comment: Since the scoring isn't based solely on code length, maybe [code-challenge] is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

### Validate the traversals

Given inorder and preorder traversals of a binary tree, return a truthy or falsy value depending on whether they could be from the same tree.

Input can be strings of characters or arrays of characters or numbers, whatever is the most convenient. You can assume both inputs are the same length.

Examples:

```
inorder: A
preorder: A
result: true
example:
A

inorder: AB
preorder: AB
result: true
example:
A
 \
  B

inorder: AB
preorder: BA
result: true
example:
  B
 /
A

inorder: ABC
preorder: BCA
result: false
possible inorder trees:
    C   C   B   A   A
   /   /   / \   \   \
  B   A   A   C   C   B
 /     \         /     \
A       B       B       C
 CBA  CAB  BAC  ACB  ABC
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: The test cases should include some which repeat characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'll have to make it clear in the question that the characters won't be repeated, as they're supposed to refer to different nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

## Illuminati is Illuminati

This is a popularity contest inspired by a dedicated scratch programmer who made the program here: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/117836320/. What the program does, is it takes in a string, and links the string to the Illuminati. This scratch program is especially popular because it demonstrates meta-satire on linking things to other things.

### challenge

Your job is to more or less produce something of similar function and form to the one linked above.

### Input:

Your program can take anything as an input, however, it has to be able to take something. My suggestion is a string.

### Output:

Your program must output a series of links that make *some* sense, and eventually link your input to the illuminati.
The last output of your program must be some variation of [input] + " is Illuminati confirmed."

### Scoring:

This is a popularity challenge. Your code isn't supposed to look great, or even execute well, so long as it has the most up votes. You must use a code that has a free compiler, and you must post your source code along with your program.

## Tips and tricks:

This section will be updated, as people post suggestions in the comments.

- The Illuminati music in the background could add some spiff to your program. you can download it here: http://www.aiomp3.com/download.php?mp3=hAAlDoAtV7Y
- Unlike what the program listed above does, there are many more links to have done besides the number of letters an a string. try looking for anagrams, or similar words.

Comment: A question should ideally be self-contained. Without reading the external link, which could 404 tomorrow, I have no idea what you want the program to do.

Comment: @PeterTaylor the link will not 404. it's a permalink..... and you should know what I want it to do, I put in my post "What the program does, is it takes in a string, and links the string to the Illuminati." and "Your job is to more or less produce something of similar function and form to the one linked above."

Comment: Seems humorous, give some examples. Also be more specific on what "*links the string to the illuminati*" means.

Answer (score 0):

## Pitchers and Rivers

Credit for the idea for this challenge goes to Dan Garcia of UC Berkeley.

Many of you may have heard of any number of variations on the [pitcher problem](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/pdf/v1ch14.pdf).  For those who haven't, or need a refresher, the generalized form of the pitcher problem is as follows:

> Given a list of pitchers of known size and a river filled with infinite water, how can you obtain a specific amount of water?

For a more specific example:

> Given a 3-liter pitcher, a 7-liter pitcher, and a river, you can obtain exactly 2 liters as follows:
>
> 1. Fill the 3-liter pitcher.
> 2. Pour the 3-liter pitcher into the 7-liter pitcher.
> 3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 again twice.
> 4. If you didn't spill any extra water when filling the 7-liter pitcher the third time, the 3-liter pitcher will now contain 2 liters.
>
> You cannot pour out part of the pitcher unless you can measure how much you poured out by filling something else up, e.g. another pitcher.

Your goal, now, is to determining which amounts of water you can get from your pitchers, given their sizes... but generalized to any number of pitchers.

### Input

You will receive the pitcher sizes in any reasonable format.  A (non-exhaustive) list of examples are:

1. A newline-separated list.  `5\n13\n532`
2. A Pythonic list. `[3,7,13,22]`
3. Prompt for input, like BF's `.[>.]`

You do not have to handle invalid input (e.g. negative sizes, empty lists)

### Output

A list of obtainable (measurable) amounts of water, in any reasonable format. You may include 0, but you do not need to.  You do **not** need to list the steps by which you obtain these quantities.

```
[3,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

[3,3] -> [3,6]

[4,6] -> [2,4,6,8,10]

[7, 5, 3, 2] -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

[30, 15, 5] -> [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

[5,0] -> [0, 5]

[-1] -> Undefined behavior; sizes are always positive
```

[Reference solution in Pyth, barely golfed](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=D%25NGR%3F%3EJ%2B%40%3DYNhG%40NeGK%40QeGXXYeGKhG-JKXXYeGJhG0%29S%7BsMs.u%7Bsm_%2B%2B%2B%5Dd%25Ld.PUld2XR%3DYd_%40dkUldXR%3DYd%2B_%40dk%40QkUldN%5D&input=%5B16%2C+5%2C+3%5D&debug=0) (100 bytes)

Comment: I would suggest `[4,6] -> [2,4,6,8,10]` as another test case.

Comment: This [has been asked before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5409/194), although it's closed and definitely abandoned. It would be nice to ensure that your spec is compatible with the two existing answers and see whether the mods will merge the old question into the new one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The goal of this challenge seems very different from the one linked; that one asks for the list of steps to get a specific target goal and mine asks what target goals are reachable.  Also, my question allows for multiple pitchers to be combined in order to get the measurements, while that challenge requires that all the water end up in one pitcher.  I believe these are two completely different challenges.

Comment: "*that one asks for the list of steps to get a specific target goal and mine asks what target goals are reachable*" are fundamentally the same thing. The algorithm is identical: the only difference is the output format. "*Also, my question allows for multiple pitchers to be combined in order to get the measurements*" Does it? I can't see that in the question.

Comment: The major difference is that mine doesn't require you to compute the steps (as there are characterizations of these lists that do not involve computing individual steps; part of the challenge may be finding these characterizations.)  I didn't include anything saying that you may combine the pitchers because, at the time, I hadn't thought that the distinction would need to be made.  However, in the sample outputs you can notice that I include values up to the sum of the pitcher sizes, as opposed to up to the maximum pitcher size.

Comment: Is the solution just multiples of the gcd up to the sum of the inputs? If not, you need test cases that show this.

Comment: @xnor, to be honest, I don't know for sure.  What test cases would you recommend, though?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest figuring out a solution or having a reference implementation to generate lots of cases before posting this to avoid disagreements as to whether a submitted solution works.

Comment: @xnor A reference solution has been added.  Anything else I should add?

Comment: @StevenH. You should add more test cases, especially ones with more inputs, ones that given unexpected results, ones that break the gcd pattern if they exist, etc

Comment: All the examples I tried on the Pyth app follow the gcd pattern. You could try iterating or generate random examples to look for exceptions. I found proofs that it holds for 2 jugs, maybe one can induct the same onto n jugs. (Edit: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.6047&rep=rep1&type=pdf) proves it) If it holds, I think that's unfortunate because it gives a simple direct solution that doesn't require doing anything specific to the bucket problem. Maybe you could require more output.

Comment: @xnor how about mapping all the reachable bucket states to their total amount of water?  I'd submit the (slightly modified) Pyth solution as an actual answer in that case.

Comment: What mapping do you mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that someone [posted almost the same challenge now](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94202/the-decanting-problem#comment229322_94202) (presumably unknowingly).

Answer (score 0):

### Translate an SVG path

An SVG path consists of a number of components. Each component begins with a letter, which may be upper case for an absolute position or lower case for a relative position. The component then has a variable number of parameters. Parameters may be separated by commas or spaces.

For the purposes of this question, you will not need to support the `H`, `L` or `A` commands. This means that each component accepts an even number of parameters, and that alternate parameters refer to the X and Y coordinates.

Given an SVG path and X and Y displacements, please output the translated path.

Input and output should be in any reasonable format, as long as you are consistent, i.e. both coordinates should be in the same format, or they can use a Point type, while the output path should be in the same format as the input path.

Please avoid floating-point errors e.g. adding 0.1 to 0.1 and getting 0.199996 like Inkscape does when I asked it to do this.

Example:

```
Input:
6.4
6.4
M 6.4 12.8 L 19.2 25.6 l 6.4 -6.4 z

Output:
M 12.8 19.2 L 25.6 32 l 6.4 -6.4 z
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins.

Comment: Does "exact arithmetic" mean use of floating point is forbidden?

Comment: @trichoplax By "exact arithmetic", I mean that you should ensure that you don't introduce floating-point accuracy errors in your output. The input list may be absolute or relative depending on whether the command letters are in upper or lower case. Relative coordinates do not need to be adjusted, of course.

Comment: It's worth including a summary of what commands need to be supported, and how each works.

Comment: Using floating point variables will introduce floating point errors for some values. Do you want to specify a minimum required accuracy, or do you want to insist on only number types that do not share the problems of floating point?

Comment: The numbers won't need huge amounts of accuracy, so I don't care how you represent the numbers internally, as long as the output contains no floating-point errors.

Comment: The problem is it's hard to avoid floating point errors without knowing what accuracy the inputs will have.

Answer (score 0):

## Pointfree Generator -- this is a draft.... --

### What is this?

From Wikipedia's page:

```
Tacit programming, also called point-free style, is a programming paradigm 
in which function definitions do not identify the arguments
(or "points") on which they operate
```

### Challenge

In this challenge, you will have to generate Haskell code in pointfree style. You can provide an answer in any language of your choice as long as it generates Haskell code.

The functions to generate will be polynomial function of multiple variables with integer coefficients like :
`f : x,y,z -> x^8*y*z + 3*y + 12`

for example, the function `f : x -> x² + 3x` can be written in pointfree Haskell like this `(3*)>>=flip((+).(^2))` or `(+3)>>=(*)`

### Input

The input is a list of list of coefficients and exponants :
For example, the `f : x,y,z -> x^8*y*z + 3*y + 12` function will be defined as `[[1,8,1,1],[3,0,1],[12]]`

### Output

### Restrictions

Haskell function/operators allowed are the following :
`(+)`,`(-)`,`(*)`,`(.)`,`(^)`,`flip`,`(=<<)`,`(>>=)`

### Hints

### Testing

### Scoring

Answer (score 0):

## Quine and Antiquine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Your task is to make two different program, A and B. Both are nonempty proper quine. However, there is a restriction.

1. AB and BA produce no output.
2. CABD and CBAD will do the same thing as CD, where C and D are any (potentially empty) strings made up of copies of A and B. E.g. ABBABA and ABBBAA should behave identically (here, C = ABB and D = A).

The score is the sum of the length of A and B.

Example:

A program written in DJam:

program A :

```
abcd
```

program B :

```
efgh
```

Then, these output are sastified

```
abcdefgh
>> <empty output>
abcdabcdefgh
>> abcd
abcdabcdefghabcdefgh
>> abcd
```

Comment: Are proper quines required? Do `A` and `B` have to be different?

Comment: "where C and D is any string, if C and D consist entirely of A and B." I don't understand this part, would you mind rephrasing it?

Comment: @MartinEnder Sorry if my English is not good. But I mean string S where S = e | S A | S B where e is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

### Code Golf: Convert to base 6 and back

If given a number, convert it to base 6. You can assume it is positive. You can get the number through any of these methods: STDIN, or ask for user input. If `i` has a `'o'` at the end of it then assume the number is base 6 and convert it to a decimal number. Assume `i` is a string.

Example:
Given `i` convert it. So if `i = 12` then return `20`.
Given `i` convert it. so if `i = 12o` then return `8`

Comment: I don't think this really adds anything to the dozens of [tag:base-conversion] challenges we already have and is likely to be closed as a duplicate of one of the simpler ones.

Answer (score 0):

### Periodic Pillbox Problem [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Pill-popping Patty is prescribed to take a particular pharmaceutical every *P* days. Presently, Phil has punked Patty's pill-box, punching holes in particular weekday's plastic pockets. Patty proceeds to plan pills *P* days apart whenever possible, but places pills in the preceding day's plastic pocket if the preferred pocket is punctured. Produce a pill planning chart presuming Patty popped her prior pill on the penultimate day of the previous week.

*In case it's not clear, [this](http://c8.staticflickr.com/2/1523/24888074919_ff08ec8e8e_z.jpg) is the kind of pill-box I am referring to.*

---

**Input:**
The number *P*, followed by the 1 to 6 weekdays that Phil punctured. Beginning with Sunday(`N`) the weekdays are `N` `M` `T` `W` `R` `F` `S`.
For instance `5MRF` means Patty aims to wait 5 days after each pill, but cannot plan pills on Monday, Thursday, or Friday.

*You can have the input with a single space after the number (e.g. `5 MRF`) or with spaces after the number and each day (e.g. `5 M R F`).*

**Process:**
Given `5MRF` Patty's first pill is taken on the first Wednesday (*5 days from last Friday*). Her second pill should be taken on the second Monday(*5 days from the first Wednesday*), but is moved up to the second Sunday because Monday is punctured. Her third pill should be taken on the second Friday(*5 days from Sunday, not Monday*), but is moved up to the second Wednesday because Friday and Thursday are both punctured. She continues in this manner indefinitely.

Note on the first week Patty's pillbox contains one pill on Wednesday, on the second and future weeks it contains pills on Sunday and Wednesday.

**Output:**
The pill planning chart shall indicate the state of Patty's pill-box each week, one week per line. Days she does not take her pill must have a dot `·`. Days she takes her pill must have a capital `X`. The chart must stop as soon as the cycle occurs (i.e. *in the fewest lines possible*) with an arrow `>` pointing the first week in the cycle on the left. All weekdays must align in singly spaced columns with Sunday on the left.

**Notes:**
*You may assume Phil was not malicious enough to puncture P consecutive days of the weeks, and that P is between 2 and 7 inclusive.*

*If Patty can't take her pill on the first Sunday, she takes it on the previous Saturday. Her pillbox was not damaged last week.*

*A cycle has occurred when pills are being taken on the same weekdays as in an earlier week.*

*Patty never waits more than P days to take her pill.*

---

**Testcase 1: `5MRF`**

```
  · · · X · · ·
> X · · X · · ·
```

**Testcase 2: `5MR`**

```
> · · · X · · ·
  X · · · · X ·
```

**Testcase 3: `5MF`**

```
  · · · X · · ·
> X · · · X · ·
  · · X · · · ·
```

**Testcase 4: `6NTFS`**

```
  · · · · X · ·
> · · · X · · ·
  · X · · X · ·
```

---

A reference solution in C++ is provided [here](http://ideone.com/FgU4Yl).

---

***For The Sandbox...***
*First Challenge. Hooray! My biggest concern is whether or not there is anything with a similar process, I'm not sure if there is a generalization or a name for this sort of elimination thing. Barring that, is a good golfing question, can it be made a better golfing question, is clear what has to be done, etc. Really any advice is welcome.*

Comment: 1. "*For instance 5MRF means Patty aims to wait 5 days after each pill, but cannot plan pills on Monday, Thursday, or Friday.*" So what does that mean in terms of the actual days in which she takes the pill? I think that she ends up taking them too frequently rather than averaging out in the long-term, but I had to try to figure that out by reverse engineering the test cases. 2. "*followed by the 1 to 6 weekdays that Phil punctured ... P is between 2 and 7 inclusive*" seems contradictory.

Comment: @PeteTaylor, Okay... I've added a plain English example of the process. Yes, Patty takes her pills too often. To point 2, I don't see the contradiction, P is the days she waits to take a pill, not how many days Phil punchs. Her process would never work with say `1W`, or `7NMTWRFS`.

Answer (score 0):

## Checkmate (aka the urinal problem) V2

inspired by [Checkmate (aka the urinal problem)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94074/checkmate-aka-the-urinal-problem)

given a non-negative integer `n`, assume there are `n` urinals.

also assume that you are not allowed to use an urinal when

- it is out of order.
- or a neighboring urinal is occupied.

If no urinal is available, the situation is considered checkmate.

**Challenge:**

Create a program or function that finds and prints (or returns, or yields) all possible checkmate combinations for `n` urinals.

**Input**: STDIN, command line argument or function argument

**Output**: Any output that makes the combinations clear is accepted.

---

TODO: add visual and test cases.

a thought:
This cries for string operations; how about a bonus for a calculational solution? Do bonuses suck?

Comment: You say "out of order" but then don't mention it again. How does that change things and how is it given in input (if it is)?

Comment: @Geobits I hope the edit clarifies.

Comment: [Yes, bonuses suck.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8106#8106)

Comment: Do you have a reference implementation? Have you checked for the sequence on OEIS? (I ask the second question because once I saw the OEIS page for yesterday's urinal challenge I was tempted to vote to close as a dupe of a Fibonacci question because the sequence was so similar).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: not yet. and: I don´t even know OEIS. Why should I check it?

Comment: The [Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) is the biggest repository of integer sequences that I know of. Whenever an integer sequence question is asked, people will look there for formulae. Now: having re-read this question and on the assumption that any number of urinals can be out of order, this is asking for sequences of length `n` over the alphabet `01` avoiding the substring `11`. They're counted by the Fibonacci numbers, so there's a good chance that there's an earlier question close enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: I believe f(n) = f(n-1) + 3f(n-2) + 2f(n-3), with some boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Compute The anti-derivative of a non-constant function**

Most of us know how anti derivatives work. They are basically the sums of infinite number of very small elements (or units).

The challenge here is to calculate anti derivative of a function (NON CONSTANT). using any programming language except the ones which calculate anti derivatives directly (Mathematica for instance).

Anti derivatives which have been calculated must be done by the usual summation  method which is basically the definition of the integral. Summation of y.dx over some interval of x)

You basically have to find the anti derivative WITH limits i.e. definite integral of a non constant function in between two user specified limits

Comment: As it stands this would get closed very quickly as "Unclear what you're asking". Even at the very basic level of whether you want symbolic or numeric integration, there are hints pulling in opposite directions. Either way, you need a specification of the input format; if you want quadrature you need to specify constraints on the rule; and you need to avoid duplicating http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2072/194 and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66714/194

Comment: I though the challenge is about finding a sybolic anti-derivative, not a numeric definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

## Download  a file [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your boss wants you to make a comprehensive download utility. She uses [Microsoft Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob) and thinks shorter code is better code.

**The Gist:** In as few bytes as possible, given an input URL, output the file to stdout.

#### Input

- You will be given a fully qualified (w/ http/https) URL.
- Download link may redirect. Follow all redirects.
- Any non 2xx-3xx status code should be interpreted as an error. Exit with a status code of zero.
- **Verify SSL certificates** - exit with 0 if invalid

#### Misc

- Do not use a preexisting utility already designed for downloading files, such as `wget`. This is considered cheating.

Comment: I'd consider this a chameleon challenge. Validating an SSL certificate is harder than all other parts combined. It also needs some clarification. Which SSL certificates are considered valid?

Comment: @Dennis hm, libraries should exist...

Comment: 1. For those languages which do have SSL libraries (which isn't all of them), there are often options. E.g. there could be an option to accept or reject self-signed certs. There could be an option to accept or reject certs whose chain includes MD5 or key sizes smaller than 256 bits. Those options may vary between libraries or distros. So Dennis is right to ask for a clear definition of "valid". 2. What's the distinction between libraries which do that level of checking and "*a preexisting utility*"?

Comment: Someone might download a virus...

Answer (score 0):

## Handwriting Recognition

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

[The MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is a series of handwritten digits used as a standard testbed for machine learning, pattern recognition techniques. Each image is of a single digit, `0-9`; as a `28x28` pixel grayscale matrix with values from `0-255`.

[image: MNIST example images]

The challenge is to create a classifier for MNIST that scores an Error Rate of less than `[TBD]` in the least number of bytes possible.

Your program must take a `28x28` 2d array in whatever format is applicable for your language representing a single image. For example, the input for the first digit might be:

```
[[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3, 18, 18, 18,126,136,175, 26,166,255,247,127,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 30, 36, 94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251, 93, 82, 82, 56, 39,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 80,156,107,253,253,205, 11,  0, 43,154,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  1,154,253, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,139,253,190,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,190,253, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 35,241,225,160,108,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 81,240,253,253,119, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 45,186,253,253,150, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 93,252,253,187,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,249,253,249, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 46,130,183,253,253,207,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201, 78,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 23, 66,213,253,253,253,253,198, 81,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195, 80,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0, 55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132, 16,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
```

### Conditions:

- This is code golf. The shortest piece of code that meets the criteria wins.
- The code must take a provided `28x28` input and attempt to classify it.
- Testing will take place on my computer at 12pm AEST on Saturday the . I will run each classifier over a set of 1000 images. To be considered, it must correctly classify `[TBD]` of them. If I can't get your code to run, it wont be counted, so help with loading the images in your language would be appreciated.
- Standard loopholes are not permitted.

## Questions for Sandbox

- Overall thoughts on the challenge?
- Has anything been done like this before? Did it work?
- Any ideas on a good cutoff for the classifier? I was thinking around 60% correct. Though was going to have a go at it myself to see what I could reasonably achieve.
- Does the testing clause make sense? Is it reasonable? Should I put a limit on the languages?
- Since barrier to entry is a bit high (knowing how to get hold of the images, possibly some ML experience), is there anything extra I should do to make it easier to start the challenge.
- This is my first suggestion for a challenge, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I actually found a very similar question from back in 2014 (using MNIST). It had a different scoring system and some slightly different criteria and expectations. Is this still worth it? Is it late enough for others to have another go?

Comment: I don't think it's sufficiently different. If you want to provoke others to have another go, you can do so in the chat or by placing a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: 60% correct is way too leniant; current state-of-the-art techniques on this dataset "easily" reach 99+% of correct classification.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would like to congratulate you on submitting the *3000th* answer to the Sandbox! (That number includes all deleted submissions.)

Comment: @Fatalize I was thinking 60% because I wanted the emphasis to be on the code-golfing, not the machine learning. If it's lenient enough I'm hoping someone can figure out some really, really simple way that would just scrape in. All in the spirit of code golf.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was hoping that the idea of a hard limit would switch the challenge around so it's not focused on building a function that works well, but instead building a very short function that works, barely. In the original a slight improvement in code length that decreased the correct matches would be bad, whereas in this challenge decreasing the code length is always good, as long as you still sit above [TBD] correct images.

Answer (score 0):

### Largest Number Given Digits and Operators

---

**Challenge**

Given a list of digits (0-9) and operators (+, -, /, *), output the largest number that can be formed using those digits and operators, as well as the mathematical formula used to create this number.

**Rules**

- All digits and operators must be used once and only once
- Parenthesis may be used in the outputted mathematical formula
- The outputted mathematical formula must be valid in an interactive Python shell (Note, this means ["--", "---", etc.], "//", "**", and ["++", "+++", etc.] are all valid operations that can be used in the output)
- Base 10 will be used
- For multiple different formulas that result in the same maximum number, output whichever one
- Input may contain any number of digits and operators
- Answers can be a function or program, and will be scored in bytes
- No loopholes or built-ins

**Example I/O**

```
Input: [1, 4, 3, *, +]
Output: +31*4
        124

Input: [1, 2, 0, '+']
Output: +210
        210
```

Comment: won't all pluses be at the front of the output?

Comment: This is rather similar to a number of existing questions, and may be closed as a duplicate. If you want to try to get it ready to post regardless, the use of the word "*operators*" in the first sentence is misleading given the later reference to combining those characters to form operators like `**`; and the question needs a complete list of permitted operators and what they do. People shouldn't have to find a Python language reference to know what `//` means, for instance.

Comment: Related: [Largest number printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable), [Can you surpass Γ<sub>0</sub>?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13524/58880), and [What is the largest possible number that can be written in 10 seconds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343800/what-is-the-largest-possible-number-that-can-be-written-in-10-seconds).

Answer (score 0):

## The one-looper ASCII box

#### Intro

I saw this one in one of my university programming textbooks as an "advanced" exercise and I thought it would fit very well here.

#### Task

Your program have to ask for an input number and draw a box with the size of the given number and a cross in it.
Example if the number is 7:

```
+-------+
|\     /|
| \   / |
|  \ /  |
|   X   |
|  / \  |
| /   \ |
|/     \|
+-------+
```

Example if the number is 10:

```
+----------+
|\        /|
| \      / |
|  \    /  |
|   \  /   |
|    \/    |
|    /\    |
|   /  \   |
|  /    \  |
| /      \ |
|/        \|
+----------+
```

The minimum width is 1 and it looks like this:

```
+-+
|X|
+-+
```

Notice that with an odd size, there is an **X** in the middle.

#### The hard part

In your program only one function is allowed (main) and in the main function **there can be only one loop** and that loop can only have **one** statement which can't be *if*. The shortest answer wins!

*note:* Sorry for the messy description but I had to translate it from my native language.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the "C-only" part.

Comment: Language specific challenges are discouraged, as per http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/48538. Good luck.

Comment: do X without Y is confusing, especially when some internal things in languages use loops to achieve certain functionallity

Answer (score 0):

### Interpret loose ranges [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp) is an interpreted programming language that has many features, one of those features is a 1 index based range creator that works like this:

You define a range as `(INT) TO (INT)` or just `(INT)` where both or the single int can go from min to [max int32 value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number))

Then you can use those ranges to extract elements of an array without fearing to overstep it's boundaries

---

**therefore:**

`1 TO 5` generates: `{1,2,3,4,5}`

`3` generates: `{3}`

Ranges can be added up using the `AND` operator

`1 TO 5 AND 3 TO 6` generates: `{1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6}`

remember this works with negative numbers as well

`3 TO -3` generates: `{3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3}`

---

## The challenge is the following:

### Input

A character array and the previously defined range clause as a string

### Output

The elements at the 1 index based locations of the range (non existing/negative indexes translate to an empty character)

---

## How to win

Create the program with the shortest byte count

---

### Test cases:

```
input array is:
{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'}

range clause:
"1 TO 3" => {'H','e','l'}
"5" => {'o'}
"-10 TO 10" => {'','','','','','','','','','','','H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l'}
"0 AND 2 AND 4" => {'','e','l'}
"8 TO 3" => {'o','W','','o','l','l'}
"-300 AND 300" => {'',''}
```

Comment: What is the winning criterion?

Comment: correct, i forgot that! its code-golf and i dont know how to add the tag

Comment: You can place `[tag:code-golf]` near the title.

Answer (score 0):

### Balanced Columns

I have a number of paragraphs of various heights which I would like to be distributed between some columns as evenly as possible. Here *evenly* means that you should minimise the total height of the tallest column, and then maximise the height of the shortest column, excluding empty columns.

The input will be an integer, representing the number of columns to be output, and an array of integers, representing the paragraph heights in lines. There is more than one way to represent the output; it could be an array (one for each column) of arrays of paragraphs, or it could be an array (one for each paragraph) of columns. (Please indicate whether your arrays are 0- or 1-based.) You may use any convenient format for (e.g. the number of columns as a command-line parameter and the array on STDIN) for I/O.

Because the paragraphs are double-spaced, there will be at least two lines in each paragraph, but if you prefer, your answer can take the double-spacing into account internally.

Within each column, paragraphs should be listed in ascending order, and the columns should be listed in ascending order of their first paragraph. Examples:

```
2, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [2, 3, 5], [4, 6] or [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
3, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [2, 5], [3, 4], [6] or [0, 1, 1, 0, 2]
4, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [2, 3], [4], [5], [6] or [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
5, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [2, 3], [4], [5], [6] or [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note that in the last example the height could not be reduced by adding the extra column so in this case only four columns could be utilised.

Comment: If it's not a requirement to use every column (as indicated by your last example), that should be called out explicitly rather than inferred.

Comment: @TimmyD "maximise the height of the shortest column, excluding empty columns" not explicit enough for you?

Comment: Yeah, as I didn't understand that to mean that *I* could optionally choose to have empty columns if it made the output more even. Maybe "explicit" wasn't the right word in my comment, but it could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[No, this challenge is not this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51471/40695)

### Where is my error?

My compiler has broken down and now it is only showing the index of the character which the error is on.

In this challenge you will write a program to point to the given character.

### Examples

Input:

```
if (goat == Downgoat) {
    print(Downgoat));
}
```

```
43
```

Output:

```
1 | if (goat == Downgoat) {
2 |     print(Downgoat));
  |                    ^
3 | }
```

### Spec

TODO

Comment: I was going to suggest giving an {x, y} pair as input, but that would make the challenge substantially easier.

Comment: What if there are more than ten lines?

Answer (score 0):

## Is this Rubik's Cube Solvable?

The challenge: find out if a rubik's cube configuration is solvable.

Takes input as a multidimensional array. An example for a solved cube would be

```
[
 [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
 ],
 [
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1,1]
 ],
 [
  [2,2,2],
  [2,2,2],
  [2,2,2]
 ],
 [
  [3,3,3],
  [3,3,3],
  [3,3,3]
 ],
 [
  [4,4,4],
  [4,4,4],
  [4,4,4]
 ],
 [
  [5,5,5],
  [5,5,5],
  [5,5,5]
 ]
]
```

starting on the sides, going round, then top, then bottom. This input would give an output of 1, since it is solvable (very, *very* solvable). A (small) net of this solved cube would therefore be:

```
     _
 _ _|4|_
|0|1|2|3|
 ¯ ¯|5|¯
     ¯
```

The result of the program should be a truthy/falsey value, printed to STDOUT or similar. This is code-golf, so shortest answer in BYTES wins. Standard loopholes apply.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: What is the winning criterion?

Comment: shortest code. I'll add code-golf as a tag now.

Comment: I think you've got an extra `2` side in your example.

Comment: whoops. Thanks for pointing that out. I will add some test cases soon.

Comment: Add for people less familiar with the cube group that it has 12 = 2 * 2 * 3 orbits, 2 because you can't only exchange edges, 2 because you can't only flip an edge and 3 because you can't only turn a corner

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10768/194 . There's no fundamental difference between solving it and testing whether it can be solved.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd say there is a big difference. Trying to solve a cube is pointless if it's impossible to begin with. This is about spotting which cubes have been tampered with.

Comment: Do you have a reference implementation which uses an approach other than trying to solve it and seeing whether you get stuck? (Also, if it is possible to do it without solving, I strongly recommend trying to find a way to prohibit brute-force solving, because that can be very short).

Comment: Not yet, but I'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

**Image Smoothing**

Input into your program a black and white image. (png, jpg, etc)

Convert the image to a 2-d matrix of pixels. Where each index is the grayscale value of the image.

Take each index of the matrix and average the 8 pixels around it. Then replace that index with the average.

For example if you had:

```
120 80  60
20  10  30
40  100 05
```

If you were finding the average for 10, the result would be 56.875. Round to up to the nearest integer (57) and replace the index. The result of this iteration would be

```
120 80  60
20  57  30
40  100 05
```

If you are finding the average for a pixel on an edge then only take values that are valid. In the example above if you were finding the average for '20' You would only consider 112, 80, 57, 100, and 40, which is 79.4 rounded to 80.

You may start at any index of the graph but it must be in order, for example of you must go right - left, left - right, up - down, or down - up. You may not go something like randomly pick the indices to average.

Once the averaging is complete, convert the matrix back into a new image.

display the new image as the output of the program. (Or save it and add it in your solution). The result of this process should be a normal crisp looking image and the result would be a smoothed out image.

Please provide your code and start and end image (SFW please) and remember this is code-golf so the shortest code wins!

Good Luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

## Implement BozoCrack

Designed to show why MD5 is a *bad* solution to password hashing, [BozoCrack](https://github.com/juuso/BozoCrack), for the uninitiated, is a rather simple and efficient method of cracking MD5 hashes. It doesn't brute force, use rainbow tables or indeed, any sort of math at all.

Instead, it *finds* the key by searching google for the hash and comparing the hash of each word in the results with the input.

Your task is simple: given at least one valid MD5 hash in a reasonable input format, find their source texts using Google and return or print to stdout the results.

In fact, you could probably arrive at the answer by finding the word in the page with the most occurrences -- you needn't use the results for a dictionary attack, but you must use Google.

The inputs can be given as an array of strings, as program arguments, space or otherwise delimited strings on standard input or in a file, etc -- whatever's easier for you, but make sure you specify in your answer how the input is taken.

Example inputs / outputs:

```
Input                            : Output
fcf1eed8596699624167416a1e7e122e : octopus
bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb : passw0rd
d0763edaa9d9bd2a9516280e9044d885 : monkey
dfd8c10c1b9b58c8bf102225ae3be9eb : 12081977
ede6b50e7b5826fe48fc1f0fe772c48f : 1q2w3e4r5t6y
```

Of course, you may use your language's library function for computing the md5sum of a string -- but please, don't use any functions or libraries designed to solve exactly this task, e.g. Python's PyBozoCrack and the original BozoCrack.rb are disallowed.

In the unlikely event there are no results for a sum, print "NO RESULTS" to stdout instead.

Comment: Nitpicking: 1. There's nothing special about MD5 here. Using *any* hash function without a salt has the same problem. 2. It sorta *does* use rainbow tables, just not locally stored ones.

Comment: @Dennis The github description says *`Instead of rainbow tables, dictionaries, or brute force,..`*, which is even more incorrect, so I made it a little less wrong :) It does work for any hash algo but it works best for MD5

Answer (score 0):

## AlphaGo..olf?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(Slight paraphrased) Extract from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo):

> AlphaGo is a computer program developed by Google DeepMind in London to play the board game Go and is the first computer Go program has beaten a 9-dan professional without handicaps.

In order to appreciate the Go art more, let's try to simulate what happens to the game when a move is made!

### Input

The input will be:

1. a 4x4 board, (Here `.` denotes empty, `o` and `x` denotes different color of stones held by the 2 players respectively for illustration.  Any standard input formats (2d array, array as sequence of alternative moves...) are welcomed as we like nice algorithms!)
2. a move to be made (Like `A4`, `B2`.  You may also like to use 0-indexed and both numeric indices like `(0,0)..(3,3)`)  For simplicity's sake, the move to be made is always with `o` (i.e. always the same color).

### Output

The board after the move is made.  Stones of the opposite color (i.e. `x`) will be taken away iff there are no more connected `x` that has at least 1 `.` in its 4-neighbor (Up, Down, Left, Right).

### Examples

```
  Input | Move | Output
  ABCD  |      |
1 ....  | A1   | o...   (case 1: all stones remains on board)
2 ....  |      | ....
3 ..x.  |      | ..x.
4 ....  |      | ....
--------+------+--------
  ....  | B1   | .o..
  oxo.  |      | o.o.   (case 2: x taken away: the only . is taken)
  .ox.  |      | .ox.
  ....  |      | ....
--------+------+--------
  ..o.  | B1   | .oo.
  oxxo  |      | o..o   (case 3: >1 x taken away: the only . is taken)
  .oxo  |      | .o.o
  .xo.  |      | .xo.
--------+------+--------
  o.xo  | B1   | oo.o
  ..o.  |      | ..o.   (case 4: Edge case)
  ....  |      | ....
  ..o.  |      | ..o.
--------+------+--------
  x.o.  | B1   | .oo.
  ooxo  |      | ooxo   (case 5: Corner case)
  ...o  |      | ...o
  ..o.  |      | ..o.
--------+------+--------
  xxxx  | B2   | ....
  x.xx  |      | .o..   (case 6: Enclosed by Board case)
  xxxx  |      | ....
  xxxx  |      | ....
--------+------+--------
  .oxx  | C2   | .o..
  ox.x  |      | o.o.   (case 7: Enclosed by o case)
  oxxx  |      | o...
  .ooo  |      | .ooo
--------+------+--------
  .xo.  | A1   | o.o.
  xo..  |      | .o..   (case 8: taking multiple groups case)
  o...  |      | o...
  ....  |      | ....
--------+------+--------
```

## Rules

1. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) thus the shortest code wins.
2. Please kindly provide explanations and ways to test the solutions!
3. The Input board can be assumed to be correct: there will be neither `x` that without a connected `x` with `.`, nor a group of `o` surrounded by `x` without `.`
4. The Input move can be assumed to be legitimate: either it won't be a position surrounded by `x`, or it must take away some `x` to free `.` for the `o` to live. (ref. case 6, 7, 8)
5. The output must be the board, it may or may not be in the same format as the input (if you take input as 2 arrays of `o` and `x` positions, say). **Output that only shows the stones that are taken away after the move is made** will not be accepted.
6. Again, feel free to play with the standard input formats. Hope to see interesting `1` and `0` playing Go instead of `o` and `x` :P

## Meta Questions

1. I don't know if this may be too hard. Would it be better if I allow golfers to fail some test cases and get penalty instead?
2. Should I stick with a 4x4 board or I can award minus scores if the solution can work with a 19x19 board?
3. If it is a `yes` to any of the above questions, which should be the number for the penalty / award?

Thanks!

Comment: If it can work with a 4x4 board it's probably scalable. I don't see any reason to have both; 4x4 seems less daunting, but 19x19 would be more satisfying to program for, even if it is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: The explanation of what exactly the program should do is rather poor. I think I can work it out, but only because I've played Go in the past. IMO the question would be greatly improved by removing the current introduction and replacing it with an explanation of liberties (which in essence is half of the rules of Go, isn't it? That plus ko). As far as size, don't do bonuses; just require answers to handle a board of any rectangular size, with a guarantee that each line is the same length. Or maybe make each dimension at least two. Then add test cases to cover the minima.

Answer (score 0):

(Need a title.)

Your task is to write 3 programs (or functions) that check if the input is a string of balanced brackets satisfying all the following criteria:

- The number of `[]`s is always less than or equal to the number of `()`s surrounding each position.
- The number of `{}`s is always less than or equal to the sum of the numbers of `()`s and `[]`s surrounding each position.
- The number of `<>`s is always less than or equal to the product of the number of `()` `[]` and `{}`s surrounding each position.

You can assume that:

- There are only the characters `()[]` in the input of your program 1.
- There are only the characters `()[]{}` in the input of your program 2.
- There are only the characters `()[]{}<>` in the input of your program 3.

Your score is the product of (the length of each program + 1). Lowest score wins.

### Examples

(To do.)

Comment: I don't understand the first tie-breaker. What is a "*program number*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: You can choose to make up to 3 programs. Program 1 handles 2 bracket-types, Program 2 handles 3 bracket-types and Program 3 handles 4 bracket-types. If person A has made programs 1 and 2 and person B has made programs 2 and 3. Person B wins the tie-breaker as his program numbers (3,2) are higher (and thus more advanced).

Comment: If Emigna is correct that this is a task where you can choose to not do the hardest two thirds of it, then that's stupid. I had assumed that the "*up to three programs*" was to allow people to write a single program to maximise code reuse between the three subtasks, not to allow skipping the subtasks entirely.

Comment: In any case, the first 2 tie-breakers is unlikely to see use as I'm sure someone will do all 3 and then only the program lengths will determine the score.

Comment: Yes, removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

## It's time to parse (everything)!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

---

### Introduction

The real world is hard. Internet standards suck. However they're used everywhere anyways. One standard in particular has been the source of a lot of trouble and frustration.
**ASN.1**
*Abstract Syntax Notation 1*
is used in many many places (including when parsing website certificates) and now it's up to you to implement a simple ASN.1 parser in your favourite programming language!

### Specification

#### Input

Your input will be an ASN.1 encoded object. The encoding that is used will be PEM (thus it's all ASCII). You may take this input as a file, as STDIN, as a function argument as a string, as a byte sequence, whatever you like. The way your program takes the input should be documented however.

If you take file input, you may have the file name as an additional argument.
If you produce file output, you may have the file name as an additional argument.

#### Output

The output will be formatted ASCII text, this may be STDOUT, a returned string, a file, whatever, but document it.

#### What to do

You need to parse an ASN.1 object and return a nice textual representation of the content structure.
This means that there should be some sort of intendention whenever a nested structure is opened (by putting spaces or other signs in front of the identifier).
It also means that you should print the keyword whenever one is hit (also see the example).
You *may* but do not have to also output actual (decoded) contents or looked-up identifiers.

#### Warning

While I've always talked about an ASN.1 object, I actually had X.509 certificates in mind. So the parser should understand everything that occurs inside an

List of mandatory keywords:

```
SEQUENCE
OBJECT
UTCTIME
PRINTABLESTRING
SET
UTCTIME
NULL
OCTET STRING
BOOLEAN
UTF8STRING
BIT STRING
OBJECT IDENTIFIER
IA5STRING
```

#### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course, built-ins are allowed.

### Example Input and Output

Input: The Amazon.com X.509 certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[Example output:](http://lapo.it/asn1js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

```
SEQUENCE
   SEQUENCE
      [0]
         INTEGER
      INTEGER
      SEQUENCE
         OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         NULL
      SEQUENCE
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               PRINTABLESTRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               PRINTABLESTRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               PRINTABLESTRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               PRINTABLESTRING
      SEQUENCE
         UTCTIME
         UTCTIME
      SEQUENCE
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               PRINTABLESTRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               UTF8STRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               UTF8STRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               UTF8STRING
         SET
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               UTF8STRING
      SEQUENCE
         SEQUENCE
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            NULL
         BIT STRING
            SEQUENCE
               INTEGER
               INTEGER
      [3]
         SEQUENCE
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               OCTET STRING
                  SEQUENCE
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
                     [2]
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               OCTET STRING
                  SEQUENCE
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               BOOLEAN
               OCTET STRING
                  BIT STRING
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               OCTET STRING
                  SEQUENCE
                     OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                     OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               OCTET STRING
                  SEQUENCE
                     SEQUENCE
                        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                        SEQUENCE
                           SEQUENCE
                              OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                              IA5String
                           SEQUENCE
                              OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                              SEQUENCE
                                 UTF8String
            SEQUENCE
               OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               OCTET STRING
                  SEQUENCE
                     [0]
             SEQUENCE
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                OCTET STRING
                   SEQUENCE
                      SEQUENCE
                         [0]
                            [0]
                               [6]
             SEQUENCE
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                OCTET STRING
                   SEQUENCE
                      SEQUENCE
                         OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                         [6]
                      SEQUENCE
                         OBJECT IDENTIFIER
                         [6]
SEQUENCE
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER
   NULL
BIT STRING
```

### Helpful ressources

- [Reference parser](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)
- TODO: Add more useful links and actual ASN.1 parsing description

Comment: What about built-ins?

Comment: @corvus_192 if your language has a _built-in ASN.1 parser_ (!) I don't have any problems with built-ins and traditionally I always allowed them.

Answer (score 0):

## Categorize the asymptotic behavior of a consumer/producer system

Given two functions `P(t)` and `C(t)`, output the correct category for the behavior of `P(t)-C(t)` as `t` goes to positive infinity:

1. **Ideal**: `P(t)-C(t)` goes to 0.
2. **Stable**: `P(t)-C(t)` oscillates, with the time spent as a positive value equal to the time spent as a negative value within a single oscillation period.
3. **Hungry**: `P(t)-C(t)` either converges to a negative value, or oscillates, with more negative values than positive values in one oscillation period.
4. **Starved**: `P(t)-C(t)` diverges, approaching negative infinity.
5. **Saturated**: `P(t)-C(t)` either converges to a positive value, or oscillates, with more positive values than negative values in one oscillation period.
6. **Oversaturated**: `P(t)-C(t)` diverges, approaching positive infinity.

### Rules

- The expected output will always be one of the above cases - you don't have to worry about other cases
- `P(t)` and `C(t)` will always be real-valued continuous functions that only consist of the following operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation (for constants `a` and `b` and parameter `t`, `a^b`, `t^a`, and `a^t` are all allowed), principal roots (real roots, only when they exist, and only the positive root when there are 2 real roots), logarithms, and basic trigonometric functions (sine and cosine of arbitrary values, and tangent for values that are not odd multiples of `pi/2`)
- Input may be in any reasonably format (string, function object/pointer, mathematical function object, etc.)
- You may use any unambiguous set of 6 values for output (like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `[Ideal, Stable, Hungry, Starved, Saturated, Oversaturated]`, or `[0, ~, -, -∞, +, +∞]`)

### Test Cases

TBD

### Sandbox Notes

- Are the definitions and rules clear?
- Are there any I/O methods that should be explicitly allowed or forbidden that aren't covered by the current rules?

Comment: I suspect that this is extraordinarily difficult and possibly formally undecidable. See [Richardson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem).

Comment: @xnor Richardson's Theorem only applies to finding zeroes of functions and deciding if two functions are equal everywhere. It doesn't have anything to do with asymptotic behavior. As for the challenge being extraordinarily difficult - it's not meant to be an easy challenge.

Comment: Actually, I can prove it's undecidable. Let A be an elementary function for which you want to decide whether it is everywhere 0, in contradiction of Richardson's theorem. Then, `A(e^t * sin(t))` goes to 0 as t->∞ if and only A is identically 0. This is because any x for which A(x) is nonzero would correspond to an infinite number of t with `x=e^t*sin(t)`, causing the limit to be nonzero. So, by running an algorithm for your problem and checking whether it outputs (1) or not, we'd be able to solve an undecidable problem.

Comment: @xnor Good catch, I didn't consider that. Would it be possible to limit the types of functions such that it would be deciable, and all of the cases would be possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Without sin or cos, you can't get oscillation, but that's basically enough for the undecidability to apply.

Comment: @xnor Shame. I think I'll rewrite this using discrete functions, in a manner so it is decidable.

Answer (score 0):

## Quine tree

[Inspired by that really weird quine challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95367/hyper-about-quines)

For this challenge, you must construct a quine [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), which is a thing I made up, specifically an infinite binary tree.

How a quine tree works:

A quine tree has infinite nodes.

- Each node is associated with a program

  - Let X, Y, Z, be the programming languages. This program is a polyglot in X and Y. In all but the root node, it is also a polyglot in Z. Note the
  - see below for more details
- Each node has exactly two children
- Every node but the root has a parent. Their parent has the node as a child (obviously).

Programs:

- When a node's program is run in X, it produces the program of the first child of that node.
- When run in Y, it produces the program of the second child of that node.
- The programs produced must be different (node foo's program, cannot have the same output in X and Y. This output must also be different than the nodes program).
- If not the root node, when run in Z, it produces the parent of the node.

### Example

Imagine that we have the (fake) programming languages Hello, World, and Foobaz.
Say the root node is `$QQ$QQ$;`:

- when run in Hello, perhaps it produces `$QQ$QQ$;;`

  - When this is run with Hello again, perhaps produces `$QQ$QQ$;;;`
  - When this is run with World, perhaps produces `$QQ$QQ$;;Q`
  - Both these programs must produce, run in Foobaz, `$QQ$QQ$;;` (Output of root node run in Hello)
- when run in World, perhaps it produces `$QQ$QQ$;Q`

  - When this is run with Hello, perhaps produces `$QQ$QQ$;Q;`
  - When this is run with World again, perhaps produces `$QQ$QQ$;QQ`
  - Both these programs must produce, run in Foobaz, `$QQ$QQ$;Q` (Output of root node run in World)
- Both these programs, run in Foobaz, must produce `$QQ$QQ$;` (root program).

Comment: This seems like a really interesting challenge. I'm not sure how possible it is, though! Substitution languages like /// might be easiest to solve this in.

Answer (score 0):

## Fastest Cashier in the West

You're trying to design an automatic cashier that is able to dispense the correct amount of change in any denominations as quickly as possible. Your goal is to implement a program that accepts a target integer *T* ≥ 0 which is the amount you're trying to make change for, and a set of positive integers {*c*<sub>1</sub>, *c*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *c*<sub>*n*</sub>} which are the values of each coin where you have an infinite number of each, and output all possible solutions for making change with those types of coins.

For example, if you're trying to make change for 123 and the coins available are {12, 16, 20, 27}, then there are 8 possible solutions

```
12 16 20 27  (123)
 0  1  4  1  means zero 12's, one 16, four 20's, one 27
             also 0*12 + 1*16 + 4*20 + 1*27 = 123
 0  6  0  1
 1  4  1  1
 2  2  2  1
 3  0  3  1
 4  3  0  1
 5  1  1  1
 8  0  0  1
```

### Format

The input will be formatted as

```
T
N
c1
c2
...
cN
```

where `T` is the target value, `N` is the number of coins, and each `cK` is the value of coin *k*. Also, the coins will be listed in ascending order.

For example,

```
123
4
12
16
20
27
```

The output will be format as

```
x11 x12 ... x1N
x21 x22 ... x2N
...
xM1 xM2 ... xMN
```

where `M` is the number of solutions and `N` is the number of coins. Each line will contain the number of each coin needed to reach the target value separated by spaces. You may have trailing whitespace on each line.

For example, the output to the input above would be

```
0 1 4 1
0 6 0 1
1 4 1 1
2 2 2 1
3 0 3 1
4 3 0 1
5 1 1 1
8 0 0 1
```

You may output the solutions on each line in any order, but each solution must be unique.

### Rules

- This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) so your only goal is to make your program as fast as possible.
- Builtins or libraries that solve this problem directly are not allowed.
- In the interests of having fine submissions, the deadline will be by December 12, 2016, which is almost two months.
- Your program must be single-threaded. However, you are allowed to use SIMD instructions and any other features of the CPU.
- The code will be ran on my machine which uses Fedora 24 x64 and has an i7-920 with 18 GB of memory.
- Please provide compilation instructions and version information if your program requires it.
- Please do not obfuscate your code unnecessarily. If I am suspicious of certain code and/or libraries, I reserve the right to ignore your submission.
- This is optional but if you are using advanced mathematical strategies, commenting and explaining your program would be very much appreciated.

### Thoughts

The test cases will be created and provided as a download if there is interest.

For scoring, there will be a hidden dataset that is ran when the deadline is reached for final scoring purposes. After this is complete, the hidden dataset will be released along with the winner.

For extra incentive, should I increase the best answer reward by including a bounty. Or maybe for the three fastest?

Is it okay to ban commercial products as I may not have access to some of them. It wouldn't be fair to allow Mathematica and not Matlab/Maple/etc.

**@PeterTaylor**: I have an implementation in Python that uses a memoized recursive function and I would say its performance is decent at best. I do agree that I/O could be a bottleneck but I could choose test cases that have few or no solutions. Using methods to calculate the Frobenius number would help find those, but I would still like to see a few cases with a large number of solutions. I see two options. First, I could require the output to be ordered so that results could be piped into another program and avoid hitting the disk while being verified. The second is to test each program twice, first with the output enabled to check the accuracy, and if accurate, the second run would be with the output disabled to measure the execution time.

Comment: Have you written and profiled a reference implementation? I would guess that for many inputs the bottleneck is going to be I/O rather than calculation, and that should be taken into account when timing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor My response was a bit long so I added it to the question.

Comment: Also, here is a [reference implementation](http://ideone.com/M24cTs).

Comment: Please state the upper bounds for number of coins, cost, coin value, number of solutions...

Answer (score 0):

## Write machine code that also works when left rotated one byte

---

Write machine code for a CPU that runs and does something. The twist is that your code should run and do something else, without errors, if it is left rotated one byte.

Suggestions? Ideas? Thoughts? Let me know.

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: So is this "any code that doesn't crash if rotated"? Generally it's best to give a specific task, not just "do something", or else it's quite broad.

Comment: This is completely uninteresting in any instruction set which has one-byte instructions. E.g. in x86 the byte that's rotated away can be `INC`, and then the "something else" is just the same function with an offset to one of the arguments.

Comment: Far too broad, IMO. Also very, very easy in machine code dialects which have single-byte jump instructions, or any instruction that has a single-byte opcode plus X bytes of data, where X is no shorter than the length of the jump instruction; this describes almost every machine code dialect in existence.

Comment: What about reversing it?

Answer (score 0):

## Peano's quine

Your task is to write two programs in the same programming language.

The first program is simply a quine, in the following called "zero quine".

The second program, called succesdor program, is a program that gets a program text as input, and outputs another program text, according to the following rules:

- The input text is either the zero quine, or code that is (or could be) the output of another run of the successor program.
- The output is again a quine in the same language.
- The zero quine, generated quines and successor program fulfil Peano's axioms. In particular:

  1. The successor function does never output the zero quine, no matter what the input is.
  2. The successor function produces different output when acting on different valid input.

In other words, the zero quine and the successor function together allow to generate an unbounded number of quines, one for each natural number.

The score is the total number of bytes of the zero quine and the successor program together.

Note that while there are several challenges that have programs returning longer versions of itself when run, I didn't find any that has a program transforming a proper quine into another proper quine.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Comment: This is extremely similar to quine loops. It just needs a quine which has a literal (int or string) it ignores and a program which respectively increments it / appends a character to it.

Answer (score 0):

## Match the BF output [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

Your task is, when given a BF program as input and 256 `1`'s on the line after the BF program, match the amount of `1`'s equal to the value of the pointer when the program halts.

For a BF tutorial, see [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

### Example programs:

```
+++
(255 1's)

(The above program should match 3 1's.)

++[>+++>+++<<-]>
(255 1's)

(The above program should match 6 1's.)
```

### Specs:

- The tape in question is 10 long, with wrapping.
- There is wrapping for the individual values: if it goes over 256, it goes back to 0.
- There is no `,` or `.` in the BF code.
- You are guaranteed that the code will terminate.
- You may use any flavour you want.
- You may match 1's in any position, as long as you match the correct amount of 1's.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Meta stuff:

- **How hard would this be to pull off?** Is it even possible?
- Anything I could improve with explanations?

Comment: 1. I think it should be "*the value of the memory cell under the pointer*" rather than "*the value of the pointer*". 2. This is clearly impossible using regular expressions, but it is possible using Perl 5's regexes, which are Turing-complete. However, at that point you're really just using Perl wrapped in regex notation, so it's arguably a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor Your second claim is false.  With a wrap around BF becomes a finite state machine.  Thus even it's halting problem is solvable by a push down automaton (regex).  It may be extremely hard but this problem is most certainly solvable.

Comment: @WheatWizard, although my initial reaction was to agree with you, on further reflection I'm not entirely convinced. The halting problem for a finite state machine is trivial: they always halt. Since a BF program can enter an infinite loop, it's therefore not an FSM. It's true that any given program has a finite number of states, but the state includes the program counter and so the ecosystem as a whole can have an unbounded number of states. Consider that in execution we can jump back along the program string an arbitrary distance: how can a pushdown automaton remember the contents of a loop?

Comment: @PeterTaylor iirc finite state machines can loop infinitely however any loop must be periodic. I don't know why you claim finite state machines cannot loop.  Toroidal Brainfuck fits every definition of a FSM I can find at the moment. It has a finite number of states and a well defined mapping of each state to another.  I also don't understand what you mean when you say "Program counter" if you are referring to the instruction pointer it is certainly finite.  Could you clarify this? I don't mean to be argumentative, but I do disagree with you. If I am incorrect I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If it helps, the input program is guaranteed to halt. Would it be easier to decide if there are a limited number of "moves" (i.e. 30,000 moves, 1 move = any `+-><`)?

Comment: @WheatWizard, the point with FSMs and the halting problem is that each state transition occurs with one character of the input, each character of the input is processed only once, so therefore the execution time is bounded by the length of the input. On the main point, I'm not saying that you're wrong: just that I'm not convinced. Perhaps the thing to do is to edit the question to rule out "cheating" by calling out to a general-purpose programming language and then see whether anyone finds a solution.

Comment: Limiting the runtime would certainly make it doable, because then the values which the program counter (or instruction pointer, they're synonymous) can reach are bounded, and so the total number of states is bounded by the number of memory states times the number of moves. It's not a *practical* bound, but in theoretical terms it's certainly good enough.

Comment: @PeterTaylor So I'm getting the "this is impossibly hard" gist - but is it on the same level as "Tetris in GoL"? I want to make a challenge that's difficult, but not THAT difficult.

Comment: I just realized that vanilla regex (without lookarounds) is a finite state machine and *not* a push down automaton.  I think PeterTaylor is correct in assessing this as impossible.

Answer (score 0):

## Three-way meta-quine polyglot [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Produce a program A such that running it in language A produces Program B, and running program A in language B produces program C.

Program B, when run in language B produces Program A, and running program B in language A produces program C.

Program C, when run in language *A* or language *B*, prints "Wrong language!".

```
Program | Language | Result
--------|----------|----------
A       | A        | Program B
B       | B        | Program A
A       | B        | Program C
B       | A        | Program C
C       | A        | "Wrong language!" 
C       | B        | "Wrong language!"
```

Your answer should use this template:

---

## Language A/Language B, {a bytes} + {b bytes} = {total bytes} bytes

Language A:

```
a code
```

Language B:

```
b code
```

---

Source:

```
# Language A/Language B, <a bytes> + <b bytes> = <total bytes> bytes

Language A:

    a code

Language B:

    b code
```

---

- None of these programs should take input.
- Different versions of the same language count **DO NOT** as different languages.  - Languages A and B must be distinct.
- You must not read your own source code from a file. Programs may not be empty
- Standard loopholes apply.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the smallest sum of the byte counts Program A and B wins.

Comment: Downvote reason?

Comment: It's probably not possible.  I'll revert my downvote if you can find a solution within 24 hours of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Find the highest product in a grid

> The following problem was inspired by [Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) at [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net).

Write a program that takes a 2-dimensional block of digits and a number on a newline ("n") as it's input. Output value of the product of the n adjacent (read "in a straight line") digits in the that have the greatest product. Error cases don't need to be covered (eg. the grid is not rectangular, `n` is missing, `n` is bigger then the width/height as the block, etc.). Diagonal numbers are also adjacent.

**Examples:**

```
1932       
4836       
8490  -->  288
3          

53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881  -->  5832
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
4

43289
90283
03248  -->  error (print whatever)
34290
22

397432008949201741720 --> 72
2
```

Note: possible inputs below are equivalent:

```
2830
0309
8011 
4

2 8 3 0
0 3 0 9
8 0 1 1 
4

{{2, 8, 3, 0},
{0, 3, 0, 9},
{8, 0, 1, 1}}
4
```

And so on, it's not strict.

It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: @TimmyD 2-8-3-9 :P Thanks for the notice, fixed now!

Comment: PPCG as a whole isn't a fan of strict input formats. In particular, function (which are allowed by default) should probably be able to take a matrix and a separate integer as arguments.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for notifying me, I didn't see that issue since I'm new to this site. I edited my proposal a bit also.

Answer (score 0):

## Absolutely correct !

I have been given some homework, in which my Math teacher wants me to figure out what expression is represented in the graphs she gave me.
Because it is long and painful to do every single one of them by hand, I want to automate it a bit.

### The challenge

Given a graph as an input, output the equation represented, in human-readable format. That is, something like *that*:

```
y=-|x-3|+5
```

More generaly, the expression will always be of the form

```
y=±|x+a|+b
```

Where you have to replace `a` and `b` by their value. The function has to be simplified to its maximum (i.e. can not contain `+0`, `-0`, or `+|x|`);

### The input

The input is given in ASCII.

```
             \       |       /             
              \      |      /              
               \     |     /               
                \    |    /                
                 \   |   /                 
                  \  |  /                  
                   \ | /                   
                    \|/                    
---------------------V---------------------
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |                     
                     |
```

This represents the equation `y=|x|`. The graph is not always centered, and can be of any width and height.

`/`, `\` are straight lines. `A` and `V` are verteces. `-` and `|` are the axes, and `+` is their intersection (if not covered by an other character).

#### Unit

A unit is two characters. for example, `--` is one unit on the horizontal axis.

```
|
|
```

Is one unit on the vertical axis.

#### Tests

A test suite is available [here](http://hastebin.com/raw/ukehakopiw).
A line of `#`s is used to separate input from output.
Output goes first, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

## How Big is the Hyperbolic Round Table of Camelot?

There is a hyperbolic rogue-like game called [HyperRogue](http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper/), based on the truncated order-7 triangular tiling. (Each vertex is surrounded by two hexagons and one heptagon.) There is a place in this game called Camelot, where the Round Table sits. In the middle of the table is the Holy Grail. The table starts with a radius of 28, but each Holy Grail you collect increases the radius by 2. So my question is: given the number of Holy Grails collected, what is the area of the Round Table?

### Assumptions:

- The Holy Grail starts on a heptagon.
- The heptagon the Holy Grail is on is the circle of radius 0.
- A circle with radius `n+1` comprises the circle of radius `n` and all the cells touching the circle of radius `n`.

### Test Cases:

```
0 Holy Grails = 31659398 Tiles
1 Holy Grail = 93888285 Tiles
2 Holy Grails = 278432568 Tiles
```

### Winning Criterion:

Shortest code wins! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: This challenge is very unclear as it is right now. The end of the first part sounds like you are asking for `A = (28 + n*2)^2 + pi`, but instead of an area a number of tiles is given. To make it clear what exactly you are asking, you should add some graphical representation of the tiling, the circles ect.

Comment: @Laikoni I don't know how to add pictures, or format anything, actually. I'm trying to ask for calculating the area of a hyperbolic circle. Here's the image I want to add illustrating the geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:H2_tiling_237-6.png

Comment: I added some formatting. If you edit your question (and are not on mobile) in the top bar some formatting buttons appear. At the right of this bar is a `?`-icon which provides further formatting help.

Comment: @Laikoni Thanks! I am on mobile, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pay Best Card in Euchre

Input:

Firstly
An array of three cards representing the cards played by each player formatted like

```
[JD][10H][9S]
```

Representing

```
Jack of Diamonds, 10 of Hearts, and Nine of Spades.
```

As you always sit across from your team-mate in Euchre, the second element represents your team mate's play. Here, the `10H`.

Secondly
A Single Char, String, etc representing the trump suit formatted like

```
S, D, C, H
```

representing

```
Spades, Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts
```

Thirdly
an array of four cards representing your hand formatted like

```
[KD][JC][QH][AS]
```

representing

```
King of Diamonds, Jack of Clubs, Queen of Hearts, Ace of Spades
```

#### Objective:

Given the three inputs, output the best possible card to add to the cards that have been played such that it meets the following criteria:

1. It takes the hand if it can, if not output the least valuable card
2. It takes the hand if it can, however it will not trump your team mate unless it is unavoidable
3. If it can take the hand, it does so by using the least valuable card. (If you have an ace and a queen that can win the hand, you play the queen).

Output format like `[JD]`

#### Formatting

```
A - Ace
K - King
Q - Queen
J - Jack
10 - Ten
9 - Nine

H - Hearts
D - Diamonds
S - Spades
C - Clubs

10H, 9D, JD, QH, AD, 9C, 10C
```

#### Examples

In: `[QD][KD][9C]`, `"C"`, `[AH][JH][QH][9H]`

Out: `9H`

Reason: As clubs are trump, the 9C is winning the hand, we are unable to take the hand so we should discard our lowest card, here the `9H`

In: `[QD][KD][AD]`, `"H"`, `[AH][JH][QH][9H]`

Out: `9H`

Reason: As Hearts are trump, the Ace of Diamonds is currently winning the hand, we are able to trump the hand so we should use our lowest card, here the `9H`

In: `[QD][KD][10D]`, `"H"`, `[AD][JH][QH][9D]`

Out: `9D`

Reason: As diamonds are trump and we are currently winning the hand, we should play the 9D because our partner currently is winning the hand, so we want to play the `9D` over the `AD`

In: `[QH][KH][JH]`, `"D"`, `[AD][JD][QH][9D]`

Out: `QH`

Reason: As Diamonds are trump our opponents are winning with the left Bower `JH` We have the right bower but cannot trump him because QH was led and we must follow suit, the `QH`

In: `[QH][KH][JH]`, `"D"`, `[AD][JD][QC][9D]`

Out: `JD`

Reason: As Diamonds are trump our opponents are winning with the left Bower `JH` We have the right bower and since we have no `Diamonds` we can trump over him with the `JD`

#### Euchre Card Strengths

If Hearts is trump:

```
JH
JD
AH
KH
QH
10H
9H
```

See the Euchre Rules if you are unfamiliar with the strength of different cards in [Euchre](https://www.hoylegaming.com/rules/showrule.aspx?RuleID=209)

Since this is Code-Golf the shortest code wins!

Good Luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

## Python Kolmogorov Complexity Golfer

Python is actually pretty good at some Kolmogorov Complexity challenges (compared to other non-golfing languages), from string multiplication being extremely short, to defining variables requiring no types.

Your challenge is to make a program that shortens Python code for Kolmogorov Complexity challenges. You can use anything, not just the usual functions that people typically use.

Your score is the sum of all the bytes for each of the ten test cases, and the winner is the submission with the lowest score.

### Test Cases

1. [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i)
2. [It's my Birthday :D](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57277/its-my-birthday-d) (Size 5)
3. [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz)
4. [Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n) (Size 5)
5. [“99 Bottles of Beer”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer?noredirect=1&lq=1)
6. [Build me a brick wall!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99026/build-me-a-brick-wall)
7. [Quack the Angry Duck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74212/quack-the-angry-duck)
8. [Make the Mexican Wave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/make-the-mexican-wave)
9. [Print a Tabula Recta!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86986/print-a-tabula-recta)
10. [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/print-a-10-by-10-grid-of-asterisks)

I don't know about the rules for each challenge, but for this one, you may print extra spaces after each line and extra newlines at the end of the text.

### Note

I don't know how to tag this.

Answer (score 0):

## Fold the number!

Given a number *n*, fold the number as follows: (ex. `30`)

First, convert it to binary.

```
11110
```

Add one `0` to the start if it has an odd number of digits.

```
011110
```

Now, take the second half of the number, reverse it, and put it under. For example, `abcd` would turn into `ab dc` (where  is a newline):

```
011
011
```

Add one `0` to each line if it has an odd number of digits.

```
0011
0011
```

Now take the back of the whole thing and put it on the bottom, reversed:

```
00
00
11
11
```

Keep doing this until there is only one column, and read this from top to bottom.

```
00110011
```

Convert to decimal.

```
51
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

Comment: @Emigna Fixed..

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95458/folding-numbers

Comment: could add an example (could be the same) but with unique characters (like abcde, instead 11110)? to help visualize the folding

Answer (score 0):

## Enumerate all the binary matrices

Your task is to write a pair of programs or functions. The first should take a single nonnegative integer, and return some matrix where all elements are 0 or 1 (or true/false). The second should take a matrix of the same form, and return a nonnegative integer.

The two programs should form a bijection, so that every possible matrix is mapped to exactly one nonnegative integer, and every integer to the corresponding matrix. The matrix with no elements must be included, but we consider all matrices with no elements as identical (i.e, there is no 0x3 matrix.)

To clarify, the dimensions of the matrix is not a separate input. You must work out a way to represent all possible dimensions. For instance, you could start off enumerating them like this:

```
0 <-> []
1 <-> [0]
2 <-> [1]
3 <-> [0;0]
4 <-> [0;1]
5 <-> [1;0]
6 <-> [1;1]
7 <-> [0,0]
8 <-> [0,1]
9 <-> [1,0]
10 <-> [1,1]
```

But you can also enumerate them in some different order, as long as all matrices of all dimensions can be reached eventually.

You may output and input the integer as a bigint if your language supports that, or as an unbounded string or array if it doesn't. It should however not be limited to a machine word size.

You may output the matrix in any format you choose, as long as the elements of the matrix, and the rows/columns of the matrix are clearly distinguishable.

Whatever output formats you choose, the other program must accept input in the same format. Your functions or programs may opt to print the result rather than return it.

Standard loopholes are forbidden. This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [binary-matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-matrix)

Comment: 1. It would be helpful for the title to be more explicit that the size of the matrix isn't an input: my initial reaction was that this was yet another "Count from 1 to 2^x" question, and I had to read it carefully to overcome that reaction. 2. Please clarify the situation with empty matrices. Should the matrices include `0 x 1`, `2 x 0`, etc. dimensions? And if so, how can that be represented unambiguously in input?

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge

You are the owner of a local supermarket, and your cashier doesn't seem to do the work you told him/her to do. He/She is never on time, returns too much change and doesn't really show optimism at the workplace. So you, as the space saving, but ruthless owner opt to replace him/her.

## Rules

The programm should initially take 2 numbers as input, the first beeing the price, and the second the amount you are paying. If you are paying enough it should output the change in 100,50,20,10,5,2,1 notes, always maximizing the amount of high notes. If you aren't, you may output anything indicating a wrong input.

### Examples

```
cashier 100 500
4 100
0  50
0  20
0  10
0   5
0   2
0   1

cashier 600 500
0
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest byte amount wins :) Good luck!

Comment: Does the output format matter, or are we also allowed to have a different output format as long as we know how much 100 bills, 50 bills, etc. are used (like `"4x100,0x50,0x20,0x10,0x5,0x2,0x1"`) ? Also, what if the price and amount paid is exactly the same?

Comment: [related (if not duplicated)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70847/this-challenge-makes-cents)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the output format is fine. inputting the same amount paid as price results in "no chage" but the output shoudl still be 0x100...

Comment: @Rod ah ok :/ didnt find anything in the direcition mine was going. i guess the title made it less findable :/

Answer (score 0):

### Postman's Sorting

You are a postman, and you have to walk down a street, delivering letters. Odd-numbered houses are on the left, and even-numbered houses are on the right.

If you had to end up back at the beginning of the street, it would be easy: simply deliver the odd letters in ascending order and the even letters in descending order.

Instead, you need to finish at the end of the street. But you can't simply deliver the letters in ascending house number order, because you would have to cross the street so often. You need to optimise the order to minimise the number of street crossings.

Given a set of positive integers as input, your program or function should output an ordered array giving the optimal delivery sequence. You need to consider the houses in pairs: 1,2; 3,4; 5,6 etc. There are a number of cases:

- If you have no letters for a pair of houses, you simply ignore them.
- If you have letters for only one of a pair of houses, you have no choice, you must visit that house.
- If you have letters for both houses in a pair, then you want to visit the house on the same side as the house you just visited first, then cross and visit the other house.

Example: If you have letters for houses 6, 2 and 5, then you want to deliver them in the order 2, 6, 5, so as to avoid crossing the street a second time.

[Further test cases as needed to clarify comments arising while the question is in the Sandbox.]

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins!

Answer (score 0):

### Procedurally Generate a Dungeon

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation)[maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)

It's time to make the new Rogue!

Given no input, output a (randomly) procedurally generated dungeon with a start and an end. It must be possible to get from the start of the dungeon to the end.

Elements may include: (but are not limited to)

- Key
- Lock (requires key to pass)
- Boss
- Miniboss
- Test
- Reward
- Multi-key
- Multi-lock (requires `n` multi-keys to pass)
- Nothing
- Boolean switch - switch can toggle when inside this room
- Boolean gate A - only opens when switch is off
- Boolean gate B - only opens when switch is on

The output format does not matter as long as:

- The types of room is present
- The 2D spacial connection is present

### Sandbox Notes:

- Is this idea somewhat supported?
- At the moment this is very unclear (at least to me). What should I add to make it more obvious what it is programs should do?
- Creativity - the bane of the objective winning criteria. I hope to at least make it obvious whether an answer is valid.
- Too broad? I hope not because I tried to make all dungeons solvable.
- Simple answers shouldn't be upvoted and answers that output nice dungeons should be.
- Should answers have to include the critical path? That might ramp up the complexity and isn't really required apart from making sure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

## Give those numbers some space! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The numbers have had it. They're through being put in order all the time. They're all sick of their neighbors, and want to be moved as far away as possible. Your goal is to help them be happy!

The 'happiness' of a number is represented by the difference between it and it's next neighbor. For example, an ordered sequence of 0 through 9 looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 v v v v v v v v v
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 9
```

A pretty unhappy sequence. But with a little work, we can fix that!

```
0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9
 v v v v v v v v v
 2 2 2 2 7 2 2 2 2 = 23
```

In this example, we've shuffled the numbers around a little, for a total happiness of 23. Better, but I'm sure we can make them even happier!

```
0 9 1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5
 v v v v v v v v v
 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 45
```

This is the maximum happiness for this sequence. Perfect!

Our only problem is that there is a lengthy review before they can be moved around. Due to this, your code has to be as short as possible to speed up the process.

### Input

Your program or function will take a list of positive integers in any reasonable format (list, array, string, etc). The list is in ascending order.

### Output

Output is going to be a list of integers in any reasonable format, representing the sequence of numbers arranged for maximum happiness.

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"   -- A string is acceptable, as long as the numbers are separated by a character. 
"6@5@4@3@2@1@7@8@9@0"   -- Any non-numeric character is acceptable as a separator, including newlines.
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -- The list represented as an array
"0123456789"             -- Not acceptable, no way to tell which numbers are which.
```

**{I'm trying to open up the challenge to many different ways of solving, feel free to offer suggestions}**

Comment: The maximum happiness for this sequence is 45, and the challenge, as stated, will be to print "0918273645 45" in as few bytes as possible.  You might want to change the challenge to accept an arbitrary list as input, though I suspect the maximum happiness will likely be found by sorting the list, then alternating the lowest and highest remaining items in the list.

Comment: @GabrielBenamy I thought about that, which is why I disallowed hard-coding. Maybe I should put that somewhere clearer.

Comment: You should probably just say "input and output can be in any reasonable format", rather than trying to list the formats that would be useful. (For example, many esoteric languages that don't have built-in lists, integers, etc. need lists to be represented as small pieces of code within the language.)

Comment: @ais523 I wanted to be more specific with the output than the input, because I didn't want '091827364545' to be valid. I didn't think that would be too restricting.

Comment: I'd suggest requiring the output to be the arranged numbers, *or* requiring the output to be the happiness level, *or* letting answerers choose which they would like to output. For me, requiring both takes away some of the fun, because outputting multiple values is clumsy in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Generate fake PGP keys [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Input

- `public` or `private`; indicates if the header and footer should say PUBLIC or PRIVATE
- `;` - a delimiter
- Version string
- `;` - a delimiter
- Comment string

An example input would be: `public;Keybase OpenPGP v1.0.0;https://keybase.io/crypto`

### Output format

```
-----BEGIN PGP {PUBLIC|PRIVATE} KEY BLOCK-----
Version: {VERSION_STRING}
Comment: {COMMENT_STRING}
                // newline
{24 lines of alphanumeric + `/+`, 64 chars each}
{one 36 char line of alphanumeric + `/+`}
={four chars of alphanumeric + `/+`}
-----END PGP {PUBLIC|PRIVATE} KEY BLOCK-----
```

### Rules

- Your program must generate a new fake key every time it is run; and be randomly distributed

Comment: The input shouldn't be too rigid. I would recommend having 3 separate inputs (i.e. putting all into a single string is an option rather than an requirement). Public/private should be a truthy/falsy value. Also what would the version and comment strings be? I think zero or more printable ASCII should be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate the chi-squared test statistic

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

---

### Introduction

A [chi-squared test](http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx?Tutorial=AP) is a statistical test used to determine the extent of any association between two categorical varaiables. In this challenge, you will calculate the value of the chi-squared test statistic given a contingency table.

### Method

Say that we have two variables `A` and `B`, which are from a single population. `A` can take values from the categories `p`, `q`, and `r`, while `b` can take values from the categories `x`, `y`, and `z`. A sample is now taken from the population, and the frequencies of the elements of this sample that fall into each category are observed. This can be used to construct a contingency table:

```
         A
     x   y   z
  p [10, 12,  3]
B q [45,  0,  9]
  r [65, 32, 34]
```

For example, the table shows that `10` elements fall into `p` and `x`, and that no elements fall into `q` and `y`.

Next, we calculate the expected frequencies, assuming that `A` and `B` have no association. This is performed by applying the following to each entry in the contingency table, where `f_e` is the expected frequency:

[image: Expected frequency]

In this case, this yields:

```
[14.285714285714286, 5.238095238095238,  5.476190476190476 ]
[30.857142857142858, 11.314285714285715, 11.82857142857143 ]
[74.85714285714286,  27.447619047619046, 28.695238095238096]
```

Next, we calculate the contributions to the test statistic by applying the following to each entry, where `f_0` is the orignal observed frequency:

[image: Contribution to the test statistic]

In this case, this yields:

```
[1.285714285714286,  8.72900432900433,   1.1196687370600416]
[6.482142857142857,  11.314285714285715, 0.6763975155279506]
[1.2979825517993466, 0.7550444466475007, 0.9806678994199733]
```

Finally the value of the test statistic is found by summing all the elements of the contributions table, which gives:

```
32.640908336601996
```

---

## Sandbox

### To do

- Input/output, specification etc
- Test cases ([Pyth program](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smc%5E-hded2ed%2CVsQsm.ec%2asds%40CQkssQdQ&input=%5B%5B10%2C12%2C3%5D%2C%5B45%2C0%2C9%5D%2C%5B65%2C32%2C34%5D%5D&debug=0) for test cases)

Answer (score 0):

## [A Numpad's Knight Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78024/a-numpads-knight-numbers) Extended Edition

This challenge is an extension of the one linked above by Calvin, and inspired by a comment by Darrel Hoffman.

My computer has a numpad which is significantly more expansive than Calvin's. For reference, it looks like this:

```
/ * -
7 8 9 +
4 5 6 +
1 2 3 ↵
0 0 . ↵
```

denotes `numlock`, ↵ denotes `enter`.

Once again, we have a chess knight hopping around on a numpad. The objective of your program will be to determine which numbers can be generated by placing a knight on any* of these keys and letting him move around. Note that although there is only one 0 key, it's two wide so 5->0->3 is possible but 4->0->3 is not, and the `numlock` will toggle the numpad on or off, in practice this only allows a jump from 5 to 9.

'*' and '+' are unused and should never be pressed, other than that you can start your knight on any key. The knight may not press ↵ during number entry, but most end there.

Your program will for input receive a number (possibly negative, possibly containing a single decimal point `.` OR single fraction sign `/`).

Test cases:

```
Truthy:
0, 2, 5, 6, 9
-6049
3059 (note the use of `numlock`)
5.16
-61.5
4/6
-6/40
55 (you can jump on 5 or 9 more than once in a row with ...)
Falsy:
66 (... But other numbers can't reach )
8 (Not within range of ↵ key)
96 (The knight can't move like that)
405 (It's probably easier to think of the 0s as being separate keys)
```

Input will always be a valid integer, decimal float, or fraction.

Answer (score 0):

### Linify

If you perform [this algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101805/lined-up-circle-n-points) but leave out some of the lines, you can produce recognizable pictures.

[An example](http://linify.me/P5Btdiu) via Linify.me - as they [explain](http://linify.me/about),

> Linify uses a greedy randomized algorithm. First, the darkest pixel is found. Then a number of random lines are drawn through that point, and the pixel values along each line are added together. The line with the darkest average is chosen, and the value of that line is subtracted from the image. Then the whole process is started over again for however many lines we are drawing. By the nature of the algorithm, the optimal line drawing configuration is probably not achieved, but performance is far superior to the naive method of checking every line.

The concept for this site came from a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/454joy/drawing_experiment_every_line_goes_through_the/).

### Challenge

Reduce (this input photo) to a linification using N pins on the outside circle. Each line of the file should be a comma separated list of the pin number and the other pins to draw lines to.

### Scoring

(formula using code length and output quality using some sort of comparison software...)

(maybe that comparison algorithm is itself a challenge)

(maybe this linify challenge should be in black and white?)

*The Mathematica Clause*: You may import graphics and math libraries for your platform older than this post, and the code required to import them does not apply toward your byte count.

Comment: The algorithm needs some clarification. 1. What line-drawing algorithm to use? Anti-aliasing? Bresenham? 2. What is the "value of that line"? The average? Or does it mean that all pixels in the line are set to black? 3. If not in black and white, what formula should be used for the brightness? 4. Since it selects a line through the darkest point and then subtracts along that line, it seems that the darkest point should get darker still and all of the lines should pass through the same point, but that's not true of the demo images. Why not?

Comment: 1. Agreed that will need to be pinned down. 2. All pixels in the line are set to one color. 3. I don't know, so b&w is becoming more probable. 4. If you create your own via linify's front page there are both additive and subtractive methods. The example I provided probably did not use default settings.

Comment: Related: http://www.thevelop.nl/blog/2016-12-25/ThreadTone/

Answer (score 0):

### Quine Creator

Consider a program (or function or code snippet) that accepts a single string argument and returns a string result. Here's an example, which I will call Program 1, of a program that duplicates its input:

```
@echo %* %*
```

We could write a Program 2 that would take the source code of the original program and substitute a hard-coded string, so that the resulting source code would take no input and produce a fixed result. If we passed it Program 1 and "Hello, world!", it would produce a program that always outputs "Hello, world!" in duplicate:

```
@echo Hello, world! Hello, world!
```

Moving on, consider Program 3 which has the effect of Program 2 with the same string for both the source code and the hard-coded string, so for input of Program 1 this would result in something like this:

```
@echo @echo %* @echo %*
```

All that remains is to invoke Program 3 with its own source code as its input. Program 3 will then create a program that invokes Program 3 with the source code of Program 3 as its input. In other words, a quine!

Please provide the source to Program 3.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest resulting [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) wins.

Comment: What are the requirements for an answer to be valid? In the "loose" end, you could require only that the answer produces a quine when given its own source as input. In the "strict" end, you could require that the answer can be given an arbitrary program **P** as input, and it should return a new program that has the same effect as running **P** on its own source code. The former may be more loose that you'd like, and the latter is very difficult unless one can restrict the set of input programs in some way.

Comment: Also, [somewhat related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41375/generalized-quine-generator).

Comment: @Zgarb What sort of restrictions? At the very least I suppose I could make it clear that the answer only needs to accept a program P that accepts input in the same way as the answer does.

Comment: On a second thought, the strict version is probably not that hard in most languages, since you can restrict the input and output methods.

Comment: I don't think the example you give in the question actually works to generate a quine because it doesn't escape properly. (This technique certainly *can* produce a quine, but the escaping needs careful thought.) Also, I think the correct middleground to find is "write a program which takes a string as argument, and returns a program that executes the program represented by that string by giving it that string as input". The escaping is explicit here, and it's a task that should be possible in most languages.

Comment: @ais523 Ah, you're expecting `@echo @echo %%* @echo %%*`?

Comment: Not quite. The two echos have to be different; the first has to produce the argument itself, the second has to produce an escaped version of the argument. It's hard to do in bash, so here's a version in Python: `lambda i: print(i + "(" + repr(i) + ")")`. Giving this function its own string representation as an argument does indeed result in a quine (I just checked that); note that `i` and `repr(i)` are different, because the first needs to become code in the output program, the second needs to become a string literal.

Comment: @ais523 Sure, applying Program 3 to itself should do that, but I'm not providing an example of Program 3 applied to itself, only an example of Program 3 applied to Program 1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching for this, thinking it was a duplicate.  I was unable to find anything (hard to know what to search for), so let me know if it is.

## The Challenge

We all know how to apply `bitwise not` to a binary number.  It simply flips all the bits, so `10010` becomes `01101`.  For this challenge, we will be creating a definition for a `digitwise not`, applying the same concept to base 10.

## Digitwise Not

For this challenge, digitwise not is defined as follows.  Line up the digits 0-9.  Because 0 and 9 are endpoints of this list, they are considered "opposite", so `digitwiseNot(0) == 9`, and `digitwiseNot(9) == 0`.  The same concept applies when you go one element into the list from both ends, meaning 1 and 8 are opposite, as are 2 and 7, etc.  Full list:

```
0 <=> 9 
1 <=> 8 
2 <=> 7 
3 <=> 6 
4 <=> 5 
5 <=> 4 
6 <=> 3 
7 <=> 2 
8 <=> 1 
9 <=> 0
```

For multi-digit numbers, you apply the operation separately for each digit.  For example, `digitwiseNot(1234)` is `8765` because 1 -> 8, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 6, and 4 -> 5.

## Rules

- Take only a single input, representing an integer greater than or equal to 0 in whatever format is best for your language (stdin or function parameter, integer or string, etc)
- Produces a single output, which is the digitwise not of the input (can be returned from function or printed to stdout)
- Can be either a full program or just a function.

Comment: Looks nice, but I don't think there will be many interesting answers, because you just have to calculate `9...9` (with the same number of `9` as there are digits in the input number) minus the input number. E.g.  `digitwiseNot(1234) = 9999 - 1234 = 8765`. But of course it's a valid and well specified challenge. Maybe you should give an example for an input number with a leading `0`(or exclude such cases): Is `012 = 12 -> 87` or `012 -> 987`?

Comment: The normal name for this operation is "complement"; that might help your search (and should definitely be mentioned in the title or body of the question, so that it comes up on other people's searches). The question doesn't seem to be a duplicate. It's pretty easy, but I don't see a reason to disallow it (the main issue is that it's likely to get disproportionately many answers and upvotes, which is always annoying because it gives a bad impression of what the site's about on HNQ, but that's not really a fault of the question).

Answer (score 0):

## Christmas Present Viewing  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

You're stacking Christmas presents, and you'd like to make sure that the pile will be aesthetically pleasing from whichever side you view it, without having to actually go through all the hard work of stacking them.

Write a program that takes the size of the present stacks in the pile, and outputs what the pile will look like from all four corners.

Each present is an opaque cube that looks like this:

```
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
```

If you have two presents next to each other, for example, it would look like this, because the nearer present occludes part of the further one:

```
  +----+----+
 /    /    /|
+----+----+ |
|    |    | +
|    |    |/
+----+----+
```

Two presents with a single space gap between them would look like this:

```
  +----+    +----+
 /    /|   /    /|
+----+ |  +----+ |
|    | +  |    | + 
|    |/   |    |/
+----+    +----+
```

### Input

A two-dimensional rectangular set of integers greater than or equal to 0, representing the heights of stacks of presents in the pile, and an integer determining which corner to view it from.

For example:

```
01  1
10
```

would indicate two stacks 1 present high, that are diagonally adjacent, viewed from the corner you have assigned index 1.

You may have the corners be 0-indexed or 1-indexed and you may have them occur in any order, as long as a different corner is used for each of {0,1,2,3} or {1,2,3,4}.

### Output

An ASCII image, showing the stack from the selected corner. Parts of the presents that would be occluded by part of a present in front of them should not be shown.

- You may optionally begin and end lines with up to ten trailing spaces.
- You may optionally begin and end your output with up to seven additional newlines.

[**Sandbox note:** This is so that there can be up to one present width and depth around the drawn area. This question is supposed to be about drawing the boxes with occlusion, not working out how wide the drawing should be.]

For example, for the input given earlier, the output should look like (all four corners are given; your code need only return one at a time):

```
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+ |
 /    /|    | +
+----+ |    |/
|    | +----+
|    |/
+----+


  +----+
 /    /|
+----+----+
|   /    /|
|  +----+ |
+--|    | +
   |    |/
   +----+


         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+ |
 /    /|    | +
+----+ |    |/
|    | +----+
|    |/
+----+


  +----+
 /    /|
+----+----+
|   /    /|
|  +----+ |
+--|    | +
   |    |/
   +----+
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.
Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Tests

```
1
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+


010
101
010
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+----+
 /    /|   /    /|
+----+----+----+ |
|   /    /|    | + 
|  +----+ |    |/
+--|    | +----+
   |    |/
   +----+ 
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+----+
 /    /|   /    /|
+----+----+----+ |
|   /    /|    | + 
|  +----+ |    |/
+--|    | +----+
   |    |/
   +----+ 
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+----+
 /    /|   /    /|
+----+----+----+ |
|   /    /|    | + 
|  +----+ |    |/
+--|    | +----+
   |    |/
   +----+ 
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+----+
 /    /|   /    /|
+----+----+----+ |
|   /    /|    | + 
|  +----+ |    |/
+--|    | +----+
   |    |/
   +----+    


11
  +----+----+
 /    /    /|
+----+----+ |
|    |    | +
|    |    |/
+----+----+
    +----+
   /    /|
  +----+ |
 /    /| +
+----+ |/
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+----+
 /    /    /|
+----+----+ |
|    |    | +
|    |    |/
+----+----+
    +----+
   /    /|
  +----+ |
 /    /| +
+----+ |/
|    | +
|    |/
+----+


01
10
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+ |
 /    /|    | +
+----+ |    |/
|    | +----+
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+----+
|   /    /|
|  +----+ |
+--|    | +
   |    |/
   +----+
         +----+
        /    /|
  +----+----+ |
 /    /|    | +
+----+ |    |/
|    | +----+
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+----+
|   /    /|
|  +----+ |
+--|    | +
   |    |/
   +----+


2
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+
  +----+
 /    /|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/|
+----+ |
|    | +
|    |/
+----+


101
121
010


       +----+
    +-/    /| +----+
   / +----+ |/    /|
  +--|    | +----+ |
 /   |    |/    /| +
+----+----+----+ |/
|   /    /|    | +
|  +----+ |    |/
+--|    | +----+
   |    |/
   +----+


         +----+
      +-/    /|-+
     / +----+ |/|
    +--|    | +----+
    |  |    |/    /|
  +----+----+----+ |
 /    /    /|    | +
+----+----+ |    |/
|    |    | +----+
|    |    |/
+----+----+
         +----+
        /    /|-+
       +----+ |/|
    +--|    | +----+ 
   /   |    |/    /|
  +----+----+----+ |
 /    /|   /    /| +
+----+ |  +----+ |/
|    | +--|    | + 
|    |/   |    |/
+----+    +----+
       +----+
      /    /|-+----+
     +----+ |/    /|
  +--|    | +----+ |
 /   |    |/|    | +
+----+----+----+ |/
|   /    /    /|-+
|  +----+----+ |
+--|    |    | +
   |    |    |/
   +----+----+
```

Comment: [pretty related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/print-ascii-voxels)

Answer (score 0):

## Ordinal Representation

A trick in code golfing, especially when digit usage in a source is restricted, is to use the ordinal values of characters to reach numbers. Instead of finding a representation for a single number, you will be finding an algorithm to represent any number in terms of ordinal values.

## Challenge

Given an integer `N` from stdin, print its representation as a sum, diference, and/or product of the fewest terms taken from the range [32, 47] + [58, 126] (symbolic non-numeric characters). Parentheses are not allowed, and standard order of operations is used. There are often multiple minimal representations possible, but any one of them is acceptable.

0 < `N` < 2<sup>31</sup>

Score ranking in order of importance:

1. Shortest representation by number of terms
2. Shortest code by bytes

## Examples

```
47
/

14
=-/

2016
 *?     //Spaces may be represented as is.

1999
$*/-E

8675
U*d+K

10001
d*e-d
```

Answer (score 0):

## It's a prime time to metagolf! [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Puzzprimes

A puzzprime is a puzzle in which you have to use primes to create a number.

Say the number is 24 - one way to create 24 (using only primes) is:

```
3*2*2*2 (eq. 1)
```

Another way is:

```
5*7-11 (eq. 2)
```

The "efficiency" of answers is calculated like so:

Let's say we take `eq. 1`, which is

```
3*2*2*2
```

There are 3 operators in there, and the primes used are (in decreasing order of prime size) `1*3, 3*2`.

We can convert this to a polynomial using the cardinals of each of the primes:

```
1*3, 3*2 -> x^2 + 3x
```

We replace `x` with the amount of operators, and we get our final answer:

```
3^2 + 3*3 = 18 (eq. 1)
```

For `eq. 2`, the efficiency score is this:

```
1*11 + 1*7 + 1*5 -> x^5 + x^4 + x^3
x = 2 (operators), 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 = 56
```

The aim of a puzzprime is to score as low a score as possible.

You are allowed to use the following operators:

- basic mathematical operators (`+-*/`)
- factorial (`!`)

  - only normal factorials.
- ceiling and floor (`c()` and `f()` respectively)
- square root (`s()`)

  - no square roots of negative numbers.
- concatenation (`2 3` -> `23`)

  - each concatenation counts as an operator: `2 3 4 -> 234` is 2 operators.

### Task

Your task is to generate solutions for puzzprimes for the first 200 composite numbers above 100,000 - your final score will be the sum of all 200 scores for each number, and the lowest score wins.

### Specs and Rules:

- You must complete one puzzprime in 1 hour on a modern laptop.
- Your program must return the same value for a puzzprime every time the program is run.
- Your program must work for all puzzprimes, not just the test cases.
- You must provide your answer in this format:

  ```
  {language}, {score}
  {code}
  ```

  (Provide your answer without braces)
- You are not allowed to hardcode any answers for the most optimal solution.

### Meta:

- Is the scoring system good enough?
- Any clarifications in the explanation? Is there anything I need to patch up?
- Is this a dupe?

Comment: Have you written a brute-force implementation to see how interesting it is? I suspect that with a few exceptions for small primes the general optimal value will be `p + (p + ... + p) / p + (p - p) * ppp....p` with occasional variants such as `p + (pp + p) / p + (p - p) * ppp....p` for prime gap 12.

Answer (score 0):

## Start another process in a endless loop

Your task is to start a process (no thread!) which doesn't end, but the main program mustn't end after starting the other process. You have accomplished the task, if I can see TWO processes of your program after executing it, waiting 5 secs, and then doing rather "ps -aux" or starting the Task Manager on Windows.

This will be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, the answer with the shortest code would win.

Comment: So write a fork bomb with a 4-second sleep?

Comment: This is pretty unclear as written. Which programs are in the various processes involved? How many are involved (two, or more than two)? Which are waiting, and which are running?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that, when run from a console, will display the text already in the console, prior to running.

## Challenge

- How will the winner of the challenge will be determined?

  > The golf with the shortest length (in bytes) will win.

## Example Input and Output

Input:
(Shown is Windows)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\CSS>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B0A1-E768

 Directory of C:\Users\CSS

11/30/2016  07:18 PM    <DIR>          .
11/30/2016  07:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/01/2016  04:45 PM    <DIR>          .android
10/25/2016  12:41 PM    <DIR>          .atom
11/29/2016  05:52 PM    <DIR>          .dnx
10/27/2016  09:34 PM               148 .gitconfig
11/28/2016  03:02 PM    <DIR>          .MemuHyperv
11/29/2016  05:55 PM    <DIR>          .nuget
12/01/2016  04:42 PM    <DIR>          .oracle_jre_usage
10/26/2016  11:37 PM    <DIR>          .ssh
12/04/2016  06:20 PM    <DIR>          .VirtualBox
11/29/2016  12:56 PM    <DIR>          .vscode
11/28/2016  03:53 PM             8,528 2016-11-28-20-44-28.000-VBoxSVC.exe-2608.log
11/28/2016  05:09 PM    <DIR>          Andy
11/23/2016  10:01 AM    <DIR>          Contacts
12/11/2016  11:16 PM    <DIR>          Desktop
11/30/2016  07:35 PM    <DIR>          Documents
12/11/2016  01:43 AM    <DIR>          Downloads
11/23/2016  10:01 AM    <DIR>          Favorites
11/22/2016  07:23 PM               409 fciv.err
11/22/2016  07:21 PM               266 hi
11/23/2016  10:01 AM    <DIR>          Links
11/22/2016  04:28 PM                15 me.txt
11/28/2016  03:08 PM    <DIR>          Music
10/25/2016  12:44 AM    <DIR>          OneDrive
12/09/2016  05:57 PM    <DIR>          Pictures
11/23/2016  10:01 AM    <DIR>          Saved Games
11/24/2016  08:56 PM               151 search.bat
11/23/2016  10:01 AM    <DIR>          Searches
11/07/2016  11:00 AM                11 t.bat
11/24/2016  08:55 PM                93 update.bat
11/28/2016  03:08 PM    <DIR>          Videos
               8 File(s)          9,621 bytes
              24 Dir(s)  152,887,300,096 bytes free

C:\Users\CSS>
```

---

Output:

**The script must display something like the text above, in the sense that it must display exactly what was in the console before the script was called.**

Answer (score 0):

## Transpile Brainfuck

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck) is a very basic esolang with only 8 commands, please visit the esolangs link if you do not know the language's specification. Your job will be to transpile brainfuck into your language.

For input, your code will recieve a string of brainfuck. You can assume that all `[` and `]` will be matched properly, but the code may contain nops (characters not part of the spec).

Output should be a program written in the same language as *your* program which is functionally identicall to the passed brainfuck program.

Your brainfuck implementation should have 300000, and support integers from 0 to 127. Going off the tape should wrap to the other side, and going over 127/below 0 shoudl overflow or underflow. The generated program should generate no errors. Outputting a cell with `.` should output that number's character in ASCII, not the decimal representation of that number.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19899/8478

Answer (score 0):

## Addmod, Mulmod, Powmod

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

---

## Addmod

Imagine defining the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in terms of repeated addition or subtraction, so that *a* mod *b* is found by starting with *a* and repeatedly adding or subtracting *b* until the answer is in the range [0, *b*).

Call this operation addmod (which is equivalent to just mod), and similarly define mulmod and powmod, where the definitions are the same apart from replacing "addition or subtraction" with "multiplication or division" and "raising to the *b*<sup>th</sup> power or taking the *b*<sup>th</sup> root".

## Mulmod

*a* mulmod *b* is found by starting with *a* and repeatedly multiplying or dividing by *b* until the answer is in the range [1, *b*). Note the range here is not [0, *b*) as that would allow multiplying or dividing a number within the range without leaving the range.

## Powmod

*a* powmod *b* is found by starting with *a* and repeatedly raising to the power of *b* or 1/*b* until the answer is in the range ( ***um, I'll think about this*** ).

For powers that give more than one result, always take the one that is positive and real.

## Input

There are three input values:

- "Dividend" (*a* in "*a* mod *b*").
- "Divisor" (*b* in "*a* mod *b*").
- Function indicator. This can be one of:

  1. 0 for addmod, 1 for mulmod, 2 for powmod.
  2. 1 for addmod, 2 for mulmod, 3 for powmod.

Here "number" is not necessarily a base 10 representation, but must support non-integer input.

You may take the inputs in any defined order, or as a container holding them in any defined order.

## Input ranges

- addmod: *a* is in (-65536, 65536), *b* is in (0, 65536).
- mulmod: *a* is in [0, 65536), *b* is in (1, 65536).
- powmod: *a* is in (0, 65536), *b* is in (1, 65536).

Where [ and ] are inclusive, and ( and ) are exclusive.

## Output

A number corresponding to *a* mod *b* using the appropriate variation of mod (addmod, mulmod or powmod).

## Test cases

[ To be added ]

## Graphs?

Comment: Just for the record, I'm still in favour of limiting this to mulmod. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder I haven't ruled that out. I'm letting them all grow in parallel before deciding whether to prune.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to improve things, I have split this challenge into two parts, both currently listed in this question for the sake of keeping them together.

NOTE: "[Run a game of Flood](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113290/run-a-game-of-flood)" has now been posted.

---

## Solve a game of Flood

This is a Code Challenge with Code Golf aspects.

[Flood](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/flood.html) is a game in which the player is presented with a game board such as this:
[image: Initial Game Board]

On each turn, you choose a colour (on the link above, by clicking a square containing that colour), and the cell in the top-left corner is filled with that colour - this colour will absorb all adjacent cells with the same colour. So, for example, the first turn might be Blue, which will cause the yellow cell in the top corner to turn blue, and merge with the existing blue cell. The next turn might be Purple, which will fill both of the first two cells purple, merging them with the two-cell purple area attached to them. Then you might go Red, then Orange. With this sequence, the board will end up as:
[image: After going Blue, Purple, Red, Orange]

Your task is to write code that acts as a "solver" program/code, which reads in the initial/current state of the board, and determines the next move or the remaining moves. This code should make an effort to produce an efficient path to the solution, but you must balance this search for efficiency with the golfing effort.

Your code may make use of a simulator code (such as may be used in the "Run a game of Flood" challenge) that takes input of the current state of the board and a sequence of moves, and outputs the resulting state of the board after these moves - these must be the only inputs/outputs used by your code.

Your code must produce a solution for any initial board (not just the test boards, see below), and must be deterministic - that is, it must produce the same solution every time the same initial board is input (fixed-seed pseudorandom numbers are acceptable).

### Scoring

As noted above, this is a combination Code Golf challenge. Your goal is to minimise your score, much of which is determined by the length of your code in bytes.

Your final score is `b+2sum(n_i)+sum(d_i)`, where `b` is the total bytes of your code (simulator code does not count towards this value, but the call to simulator code *does*), `n_i` is the number of steps used by your solver program to solve each of the test boards (see below), and `d_i` is the maximal depth to which your code searches for each of the test boards before selecting a step.

The `d_i` value, here, is intended to punish those who use brute force to find the optimal solution. You need to find efficient solutions, cheaply.

### Rules and Assumptions

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Code must be able to handle non-square boards, with each dimension being anywhere between 6 and 30 cells (more is fine, it must handle this range). It must be able to handle between 3 and 9 distinct colours or "colour" labels (numbers are fine).

You may assume that input is in simplest form - that is, if there are four colours, they will be labelled 1-4, or a-d, or any other similar system as appropriate. You will not need to handle situations such as incorrect inputs, unsimplified inputs (you won't have the numbers 1, 3, 6, and 9, without the others in between, unless it suits your code).

Your code may take input indicating details of the board such as dimensions and the set of valid "colours".

Your answer should include a description of formats, etc.

Code cannot treat the test boards as special cases - that is, you cannot have the code detect which test board it is, and if it doesn't match a test board, use a generic, low-quality code for solving.

**Request**: If you believe you have identified a non-standard loophole, and it's definitely a loophole and not in the spirit of the question, please comment to have the loophole closed, rather than posting an answer using it. This is not a rule, *per se*, but an effort to keep the challenge interesting.

### Test Boards

**7x6, 6 colours**

[image: Board 1]

**12x12, 6 colours**

[image: Board 2]

**12x12, 3 colours**

[image: Board 3]

**16x16, 9 colours**

[image: Board 4]

Tags: Code-Challenge, Code-Golf, Optimization, Game

**Not sure whether this should be labelled as Code-Challenge, Code-Golf, or both**

Comment: The game itself is a nice challenge but I don't think it's a good idea to put both the simulation and the solver into the same challenge. They'd make perfectly decent separate challenges, especially since the scoring is mostly based on the solver, apart from the simulators byte count being added in.

Comment: Also, there's this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26232/8478

Comment: @MartinEnder - I'd considered having two separate challenges, but I realised that the solver code would likely require the simulation code or a variant of it, anyway. Or at least, there would be a lot of duplication between the two. Also, thanks for finding that past question - I did a quick search, but I didn't spot that particular question, for some reason (maybe I included the word "golf" in the search, I'm not sure)

Comment: Given the issue with overlap between the two parts, what do you think - split them, leave the challenge as-is, or modify the question to merge the parts into a single code (so the code has to be able to take input, but will auto-solve for some input?)

Comment: I'm definitely in favour of splitting. Especially since we've already done a solver challenge, I think just the simulation could be a really fun (and well-scoped) challenge. It could be as simple as "here is a grid and a list of moves, return whether the moves solve the grid".

Comment: @GlenO I made the edit I did because as the challenge has already been posted, it shouldn't take up vertical space for no reason.

Comment: @Okx - I understood why you made the edit, but the thing is, there were two challenges, and only one had been posted. So I reverted, then removed the one I'd already posted and replaced it with a link. What remains is the unposted one.

Answer (score 0):

### *Graph*ical Stars

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

*Meta: this is currently pretty rough so I could get some ideas down quick. I'm also probably not using the right terminology as I'm not very familiar with graphs and graph theory. Looking for feedback.*

[image: example star]

Take an input integer `50 <= n <= 300` and construct a circular graph of `n` points. Randomly connect them with `n/2` chords. Some points will likely have more than one edge - that's fine. Then, take a regular 5-pointed star of the same diameter as the circle, and use it as a stencil. Output the inner part of the star either to the screen or an image file.

Comment: You might want to find/make a better picture for this. The current one isn't a regular star.

Comment: You could also change it from "n points, with n/2 connected" to "n chords", which I think might give a better aesthetic.

Comment: @Geobits The star was taken from the header of an email Timmy got. n chords means n edges, right? Chords are generally for circles.

Comment: @Pavel I know where it came from, but while it's good for inspiration, it's misleading if that's the only one presented.

Comment: @Geobits Dang, you're right - the edges aren't *quite* straight across. I'll need to construct a different image. Thanks!

Comment: "Output the inner part of the star either to the screen or an image file." So should the outline of the star not be output?

Comment: @MartinEnder I see how that wording is confusing. When I have got my updated star, I'll edit that section appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

## Radiation hardening meta-program (Cops)

Nuclear winter is coming, so you feel the need to radiation harden every program you've ever made in order to preserve your sanity during the fallout. Unfortunately, time is short, so you have to pick and choose which functionality to support.

Write a program that can take any valid program in the same language as input. Your program must then output a radiation hardened program that should do the same thing. Note that [verifying that two programs are functionally equivalent is a form of the halting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132051/is-finding-the-equivalence-of-two-functions-undecidable/1132167#1132167).

A counterexample will be a valid input program where the output will not be a correct, radiation-hardened version of the input. It is the job of the robber to find any such valid counterexample, showing that your meta-program is not a complete solution.

---

## Radiation hardening meta-program (Robbers)

Nuclear winter is coming, and your buddy has gone insane. He claims he has a program that will save his sanity and preserve his life's work. You need to prove him wrong, because that's on your bucket list and time is short.

Find a valid program in the same language as the meta-program that, when given as input, the meta-program does not produce a correct, radiation-hardened version as output.

Comment: I think it is possible, as there are standard formats for radiation hardened programs in most 2D languages. The scoring method seems reasonable. +1

Comment: @Flp.Tkc The thing is that the program might be rather large to accomplish this task, and then hardening it with itself might take a long time to run. And then, how do we test programs?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc those standard formats often assume that the workload program itself can be expressed as a linear program. plus, 2D languages also will almost always have some weird features that can make any program very brittle with respect to any kind of modification (like reading the source code).

Comment: @mbomb007 The main problem I see with this challenge is verifying the correctness of solutions.

Comment: @MartinEnder Same. If someone submitted a solution, it might be really long, and the output could be many times as long as the input. Then you have to determine what inputs to test, and verify each output.

Comment: Perhaps we could go about it sort of like a KOTH. Write a controller that supports a bunch of languages, and it has a bunch of programs for each language that it will test and verify for a given submission, as well as running the submission on itself. I think the results would be worth it.

Comment: @mbomb007 Then you'll get solutions that will work exactly for these tests.

Comment: @MartinEnder So? If someone can find a counterexample, then the answer is invalidated.

Comment: Then I don't see how this helps with verifying the correctness of answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50104/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-martin-ender).

Comment: You need a requirement that the language is a programming language. (Otherwise, it can trivially be solved using a "language" in which all programs are `cat`.)

Comment: @ais523 That's really a default.

Comment: @mbomb007: There are multiple contradictory Meta posts about it. Until we can get our act together and come to a conclusion on it, it's best for challenges to say explicitly when it's relevant.

Comment: Nah. If it's not within the spirit of the challenge, it'll be pretty obvious and deleted soon after.

Answer (score 0):

## Anagrammatic quine

Your task is to create a program which is a quine, with the added challenge that all permutations of characters of the program still generate the same output as the first program.

So, for example, if your program is

```
abc
```

this program must output

```
abc
```

exactly, with optional leading or trailing newlines.

Any permutations of the program's characters, so

```
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

must also output `abc`.

## Rules:

- You must have at least 2 distinct characters in your program.
- No comments.

Comment: I doubt this is possible for quines longer than one or possibly two characters?

Comment: @StewieGriffin It's always impossible until Dennis shows up and does a less than 20-byte Jelly solution. Then it's possible. TBH, I have no idea how this is going to turn out - perhaps it's going to be like a "Tetris in GoL" question?

Comment: Less than 20, sure... more than 2 (distinct) characters; I'd be very surprised. It would mean all combination of those characters must be a quine.

Comment: @StewieGriffin In the current situation, `acb` outputs `abc`, not `acb` (so it's not a quine in itself). Would it be easier or harder if I make it a quine instead of a single output?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp depends on what you want the challenge to be. Now it's like almost impossible (though I already have a solution lol, thanks esolangs.org) ; but saying 'all permutations must be quines too' make it even harder I think.

Answer (score 0):

## Effective street lighting

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

You are the operator of a town's street lamps. Each road has one or more lamps. When it's night, every part of the road must be lit, which means that either the lamp above it, or **both** lamps next to it must be on. Your job is to light each street in the most energy-efficient way. The problem is, each lamp has its own power consumption.

### Your task:

- Take an input consisting of the consumption of each lamp in a single street;
- Output the **minimal** consumption of the street so that all spaces are lit;
- And have your program calculate this in a reasonable time (will be specified) for at least 50000 lamps with a maximum consumption of under 1000.

### Notes:

- Input can be taken in any simple list format (e.g. newline-separated; space-separated; as an array)
- There will be at least one lamp
- Each lamp's consumption will be a positive integer
- An alternative statement of the condition for a valid subset of lamps is that the first and last lamp must be lit, and no two consecutive lamps may be unlit
- The output is a single integer (and will fit in a 32-bit signed integer type)
- Trailing spaces and newlines are allowed in output

---

### Test cases:

```
10 -> 10

15 20 -> 35

10 20 40 30 30 40 -> 100

534 954 444 154 431 818 550 486 294 449 247 766 216 400 924 728 821 845 724 807 585 555 379 939 591 601 263 76 976 567 -> 7646

12 357 925 826 727 565 444 897 474 546 564 306 931 293 503 895 320 79 790 241 441 301 423 290 390 556 529 797 123 292 692 653 648 336 480 95 619 923 710 93 188 992 118 120 5 339 733 324 417 242 284 857 542 706 866 651 262 395 448 103 686 858 756 54 195 954 866 813 877 295 625 784 287 461 903 291 799 636 334 216 878 617 791 139 323 657 789 303 770 956 406 176 814 880 229 727 834 813 260 711 108 884 495 394 64 117 404 862 472 737 796 69 354 587 207 676 963 715 697 733 671 103 908 204 982 855 931 535 668 909 247 775 793 460 888 575 296 292 437 767 747 951 835 101 538 42 495 220 756 192 672 146 14 580 350 714 155 999 250 822 908 215 317 420 674 923 994 969 933 150 455 680 101 290 780 357 332 993 577 806 185 249 671 916 547 21 631 701 738 880 243 646 95 278 66 487 201 778 176 852 927 630 532 746 920 31 103 970 24 398 495 926 365 166 843 912 186 474 332 642 73 293 288 167 570 72 653 489 849 547 341 776 178 591 241 98 340 344 786 363 741 281 9 825 447 570 456 351 44 787 993 116 799 281 1 88 353 372 577 920 919 636 697 97 946 937 912 286 999 698 368 460 978 95 285 425 664 740 495 707 246 488 541 763 487 260 851 558 631 147 479 550 782 894 365 447 550 277 452 550 974 819 10 672 913 13 815 296 471 310 721 435 516 262 199 4 240 50 561 870 196 40 140 696 652 504 862 203 500 314 752 193 133 480 864 764 211 399 60 681 708 499 834 225 479 33 946 718 800 226 307 714 984 446 411 636 669 273 838 887 305 590 80 437 788 663 919 998 780 697 398 488 196 233 431 674 983 96 392 784 322 698 217 306 863 346 941 251 337 780 138 641 89 935 796 877 598 715 594 378 131 992 585 326 943 734 718 926 830 828 429 870 246 365 176 109 710 835 359 48 615 215 688 423 150 485 19 467 918 612 844 50 323 148 94 984 601 531 630 431 359 59 20 323 142 195 150 852 748 227 899 83 441 306 505 591 509 523 58 147 853 620 914 895 487 8 879 88 257 509 237 335 287 256 657 428 450 807 280 916 34 897 998 475 922 503 784 431 744 841 577 317 180 210 212 666 936 91 753 193 319 989 527 605 245 903 751 413 710 750 330 462 647 328 655 288 550 439 719 294 998 15 610 179 943 821 844 879 631 598 72 949 587 318 273 551 221 24 963 649 773 12 111 140 340 766 427 889 923 864 901 922 598 512 101 541 52 944 139 401 542 210 69 848 527 60 399 466 802 81 115 294 93 944 433 151 710 579 40 633 162 659 555 478 171 374 737 941 319 875 61 579 804 130 146 50 189 263 516 709 344 349 4 155 293 436 305 721 733 63 74 614 721 347 92 611 721 548 271 758 423 331 337 227 179 483 277 87 745 511 795 807 859 798 961 153 953 984 592 686 47 665 300 487 13 111 98 452 658 368 210 799 417 546 27 596 747 22 682 493 532 477 300 391 994 980 262 947 964 854 633 730 519 652 217 250 481 314 701 139 400 910 937 535 457 682 131 204 703 531 415 235 727 434 345 721 414 606 668 97 460 20 826 698 671 43 947 152 75 649 9 193 559 665 728 16 347 577 938 769 109 72 722 835 505 67 556 637 673 942 453 851 961 279 549 633 41 497 503 833 146 231 745 704 895 473 439 960 768 96 729 876 167 452 430 672 237 704 28 909 646 480 761 608 478 310 959 237 806 181 70 670 411 533 375 25 6 532 985 493 627 433 369 793 603 518 465 840 222 212 749 868 691 229 195 169 539 154 405 64 334 194 734 464 726 827 488 451 359 473 943 985 625 31 778 228 548 962 68 489 174 536 357 583 764 551 471 22 423 875 804 475 787 257 938 233 84 427 402 161 618 345 146 243 94 642 190 361 604 975 849 496 230 924 80 994 194 550 734 616 144 257 91 650 232 748 882 315 893 284 194 511 347 339 473 159 981 381 519 304 356 368 519 586 11 317 299 204 585 751 538 447 727 348 97 958 96 697 274 988 699 467 499 764 525 690 923 225 71 161 247 146 248 765 731 258 82 748 462 666 499 999 114 226 347 928 185 161 345 177 149 762 362 367 527 605 57 169 829 846 329 77 991 576 560 441 553 642 189 15 27 687 732 858 632 80 506 816 240 850 711 108 612 73 474 857 678 249 26 226 813 355 302 523 649 581 963 202 223 152 934 967 558 667 826 190 465 332 724 423 900 435 530 512 226 722 89 622 690 114 848 503 187 868 27 555 449 989 756 390 860 410 358 418 77 184 326 260 234 50 682 852 484 931 83 428 653 171 51 343 285 898 565 190 485 310 744 934 299 220 324 877 629 400 295 424 302 339 683 535 388 84 387 590 15 189 19 387 359 69 448 643 685 13 833 170 322 296 822 340 515 147 935 862 265 949 286 567 288 687 820 676 490 926 984 504 115 3 609 473 789 58 835 474 788 387 363 829 682 185 887 916 50 822 778 315 771 783 600 60 470 420 454 678 346 438 183 460 160 791 933 948 567 768 142 356 155 504 185 555 407 72 471 176 612 250 209 384 33 808 162 221 228 615 899 574 53 800 752 212 310 685 879 877 172 21 233 45 243 136 600 368 925 71 543 537 39 751 920 789 278 82 11 506 415 628 798 187 147 550 117 456 954 995 52 844 16 3 889 976 856 208 345 781 278 887 319 317 358 -> 245300
```

---

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

[**Sandbox note:** I'd be grateful for any help on this challenge. It looks trivial - that's what I think caused the negative feedback. Any help or notice accepted! ([*un*golfed Java program](http://pastebin.com/1JNuzrt6))]

Comment: There are quite a few minor improvements which could be made in the explanation: I'll edit in a rewrite proposal, which you can revert if you don't like it. As for being trivial: it *is* sufficiently trivial that I personally wouldn't upvote it on main (basically it's folding `min`, and the first version I wrote in CJam worked first time and is probably as short as it gets in CJam - your example Java code is far more complicated than it needs to be), but there are plenty of questions which are *more* trivial.

Comment: For "reasonable time", I think 1s would be reasonable in most languages, and I don't think anyone's likely to attempt the challenge in a language in which it wouldn't be reasonable (because working with arrays in those languages is not fun).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Firstly, thanks for the edit; I might edit again later though. As to your comments: I had designed my Java code example to give me results for 1'000'000-lamp streets, and also somewhat complicated the code before posting it here. Finally, 1s for 50000 lamps seems too much for me, but I don't think I'll put a time limitation into the final challenge. **TL;DR**: thanks for the help!

Comment: 1s for ten million lamps is generous in languages like C and Java (I get 50ms for ten million in C#), but less so for languages which run on multiple layers of interpreters. I like having a time limit, because it pushes people to think about their approach rather than brute-forcing (which is usually shorter but takes time exponential in the size of the input), but the point is to cut out exponential time solutions rather than to make the constant in linear-time solutions significant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'll consider that, thanks for informing.

Answer (score 0):

## Interweaved quine

Your task is to create a program that, when run, returns itself as output (this is known as a quine). However, this quine must, when it is copied `n` times, returns the quine, but with each of its characters duplicated in place `n` times.

If your original program is `Derp`:

```
Derp -> Derp (must return itself as output to be a quine)

DerpDerp -> DDeerrpp
(the "Derp" is copied twice, so each character in the output has to be copied twice)

DerpDerpDerp -> DDDeeerrrppp
etc. etc.
```

### Rules and Specs:

- You are allowed to have leading and/or trailing newlines in your program.
- Your program must contain at least two distinct characters (which implies that your code must be at least 2 bytes long).
- [Standard quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4924/49561) apply.

Comment: What happens if the program is copied `-1` times (ie layed out in reverse)?

Comment: @KritixiLithos It doesn't really matter, it could do whatever it wants.

Comment: The first sentence also seems unnecessarily complicated, especially for people who don't know what a quine is. How about something like "Your task is to write program which prints its own source code (a quine). However, when the program's source code is repeated N times, it should print its code with each *character* repeated N times instead." The examples could also be condensed into a single code block, which would allow you to add one or two more examples for clarity without using lots of vertical space.

Comment: You should say `n` is guaranteed to be a positive integer larger than (or equal to) 1

Answer (score 0):

## ASCII TIE-Fighter Fleet Stereogram

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[stereogram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stereogram)

---

ASCII Sterograms are pretty rare and there's been quite a few [noteable ones](http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=art%20and%20design/stereograms) that I've seen. However, there is one that I've had the most success with and it's also one of the more simple ones. I used to send this one to people on AIM way back when that existed. View the picture below, notice that it's 3 separate lines of "TIE-Fighters". For one to view the fleet in 3D, they must try to make 4 lines out of the 3 lines by crossing their eyes just enough to get it to line up perfectly. Once you see four lines the TIE Fighters should seem to "pop out".

**Give it try:**

```
      (-O-)      (-O-)      (-O-)
     |-O-|       |-O-|       |-O-|
    (-O-)        (-O-)        (-O-)
   |-O-|         |-O-|         |-O-|
  (-O-)          (-O-)          (-O-)
 |-O-|           |-O-|           |-O-|
(-O-)            (-O-)            (-O-)
```

If you can't see what I'm talking about, try being extremely close to your monitor while viewing it. If that doesn't work, try transferring it to a notepad using "Courier" as the font. If you can't see it at all, then I apologize to you for getting your hopes up.

## The Challenge

Your challenge is to take in a number `100 > n > 3` and output that many rows of TIE fighters. The fighters must be centered as shown in the example art and must alternate between the following patterns,
`(-o-)` and `|-o-|` starting with `(-o-)`. Columns should be separated initially by 6 spaces, increasing by 1 each iteration to create the forced perspective we're looking for.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: -1 for giving me a headache :p

Comment: @TimmyD try ANY of the others on the link I put. This one is tame in comparison haha

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Tic-Tac-Toe is a solved game. It is possible on current hardware to generate a complete game tree using the minimax algorithm. However, doing so is CPU and memory intensive. There are various ways of generating an incomplete game tree that will still solve the game using, for example, sorting, pruning, lookup tables and other means.

## Challenge

Your task is to code a function that, given a particular game state, will construct a game tree and "solve" the game. Your function is expected to return the best possible move given the current game state and also output the game tree, along with a total count of the nodes constructed, to the console. The objective is to generate the smallest tree, by node count, while still solving the game. The function must accept at least two arguments. 1) a string representing the game state. 2) an integer representing who's turn it is to play.

The winning entry will be the one that generates the least amount of nodes while still solving the game. If there is a tie, the function that was submitted first will win, unless the subsequent entry can be shown to run 25% faster. Scoring (number of nodes), will be done only with the input given in the input example below. Note that your function is still expected to work properly given any valid tic-tac-toe game state.

## Example Input and Output

The first agument passed to the function is the game state. It is represented by a string of 9 comma seperated integers. Each integer represents the state of a square on the tic-tac-toe board sequentially. `0` reprensents an empty square, `1` a square with an X and `-1` a square with an O.

The second argument is the player who's turn it is to make the next move. It is an integer where `1` means player X and `-1` means player O.

Input example:

> "0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0", 1

This example input represents the following game sate, with player X making the next move:
[image: Tic-Tac-Toe board]

Output:

The function will return an integer `0-8` representing the next move.

> 4

The function must also output the game tree to the console and how many nodes were created.

[image: Console]

## Final instructions

If you end up using look-up tables, they must be empty to begin with and be generated as the tree is being created/traversed.

Node values should be dependant on children terminal/leaf node actual values. Your are not allowed to use some kind of heuristic or simulation to evaluate a node. If a tree branch is not expanded all the way to terminal nodes, it must be because the algorithm figured out that it would be useless to do so or because it has already come across the same game state node elsewhere in the tree and can use that information instead of expanding further.

Answer (score 0):

## What can I spell?

My mother-in-law has a set of wooden blocks that together spell out `fRoSty The Snowman`.  Specifically, `f`, `R`, `o`, `S`, `t`, and `y` are all painted on separate blocks (note that `R` and `S` are capitalized). And then there's one longer block that says `The Snowman`.

However, each block also has a different letter on the reverse side.  For example, if you flip the `f` block around, it shows a `B`.  So you could instead spell out `BRoSty The Snowman`.  (Sidenote: Googling `Brosty the Snowman` reveals several Twitter users with that alias.  Those people are not me, and their opinions are their own.  I do not endorse their comments.)

Similarly, the reverse side of the `R` is an `e`, and on the back of the `t` is a `u`.

Or actually, I'm not really sure if that's a `u` or an `n` on the other side of the `t`.  So I guess it could really be either one!

So the full set of blocks is

`f <--> B`

`R <--> e`

`o <--> M <--> W`

`S <--> i`

`t <--> u <--> n`

`y <--> E`

`The Snowman <--> xo xo xo <--> ox ox ox`

Note that `The Snowman` has a space, and `xo xo xo` includes two spaces, as does `ox ox ox`.

Of course, when writing out a phrase you **can re-order the blocks**, you **don't have to use every block**, and you **can't use a block twice**.  (If you like: from each block, either zero or one of the two or three options may be used.)

Finally, you **can insert at most** `1` **space** in between any two blocks.  So both `fRoSty The Snowman` and `fRoStyThe Snowman` are possible, but `fRoStyTheSnowman` is not possible because the block with `The Snowman` includes a space.

So the question is, **Given a phrase, can I spell it out using these blocks?**

## Input

A string of printable-ASCII characters, of length `1` or more.  If you like, you may assume the input has only letters (`A-Z` `a-z`) and spaces  .

You may also assume that the input won't begin or end in a space, and will never have multiple spaces in a row.

You may take the input as a string or array of characters or whatever is convenient and conventional in your language.

## Output

You should output a [Truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value if the message can be spelled using the blocks, and a Falsey value otherwise.

### Truthy Examples:

`fRoSty The Snowman`

`fRoStyThe Snowman`

`SMuRfy The Snowman`

`fRy SuM ox ox ox`

`xo xo xo MRS BEn`

`xo xo xo MR BEn` (don't need to use every block)

`eW` (Both `e` and `E` appear in the set of blocks)

`WRiThe Snowman`

`R u The Snowman`

`y i M The Snowman Rn`

`BRThe Snowmano`

`Box ox oxy`

`xo xo xo`

`t o yS`

`t`

### Falsey Examples:

`The Snowman BRoW` (the `o` and `W` can't occur simultaneously)

`TheSnowman` (again, the block in question clearly reads `The Snowman`)

`The snowman` (input is case-sensitive)

`The Snowmen`

`The SMuRfy Snowman`

`nut`

`tt`

`xo xo xo The Snowman`

`aaasdf`

`xoxoxo`

`yo yo yo`

`Ho Ho Ho`

`xo xo xo MR bEn`

`More egg nog please`

### Invalid inputs (you are allowed to assume such inputs will not occur):

`The  Snowman` (adjacent multiple spaces)

(has space at the beginning/end of the string)

`fRo5ty` (only letters and spaces allowed)

`Is there any more egg nog left?`

`Should we make some more egg nog?`

`Is there any alcohol at all in the house?`

`I'll be back in a bit`

`` (The empty string)

## Other rules

My mother-in-law's Internet access is not the best, so the shorter your code, the better. Hence, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).  Shortest code wins!  You may use any of the [default input and output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and [standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

If you have a built-in that will do this for you, then I guess this is your chance to use it!  Please feel free!

## Room for improvement

Obviously, let me know if this is too close to another question, or if it's unclear.

Please let me know if you'd rather see different rules.  Please feel free to propose any suggestions that would improve the challenge.

Other test cases that I need to include?

Would different formatting be more convenient?

Comment: "*it could really be either one*" What does that mean?

Comment: I mean that the block could function as either a `u` or an `n`.  (Because if you turn a `u` upside down, it becomes an `n`.)

Comment: Well, that's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

## Create an equation who's only solution is the numerical ASCII code of the equation itself [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Your equation will be run as a Wolfram Alpha query with `Solve` prepended to it.

The equation must start with (spaces optional):

```
y = 
f(x)
g(x)
h(x)
```

Output is considered to be the string in the second box of Wolfram Alpha, after your prefix (above) is stripped. If the string is not numerical, it is disqualified.

Only [these functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_mathematical_functions&oldid=739319930) are allowed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the standard quine challenge with a language restriction slapped on top.  Its not uninteresting or boring but I and I would think others will vote to close this if it is posted as is.  I don't have any recommendations for how to fix this, but if you want to see this answered I would suggest offering a bounty rather than posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a Sound Change Applier

*(Snappier title suggestions appreciated)*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

---

### Background

[The pronunciation of human languages changes over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_change). Often, sound changes follow discernable rules, with the same change applied consistently across many words in a language. For example, a lot of words that started with *f* in Latin now start with *h* in Spanish: ***f***acere -> ***h***acer, ***f***ervere -> ***h***ervir, ***f***īcus -> ***h***igo, and ***f***īlius -> ***h***ijo.

Mark Rosenfelder, a well-known name in [conlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) circles, wrote a program called [Sound Change Applier](http://zompist.com/sca2.html) to help simulate this process. Actually, the SCA constitutes a small pattern-matching and substitution language. For this challenge, we're going to implement a pared-down version.

### The language

An SCA program transforms a list of words according to a collection of sound change rules. It consists of two sections: category definitions and substitutions.

**Category definitions** are lines of the form `V=aeiou`, where `V` is the category name (must be a single character) and `aeiou` are the category entries. Categories define groups of similar speech sounds (we'll use the term "letters," though strictly speaking that's a bit misleading); for instance, the above example is the category of vowels.

**Substitutions** are where the magic happens. They take the form `target/replacement/environment`, where the constituent parts are as follows:

- `target` and `replacement` are strings containing any number of letters and 0 or 1 category names, in any order. They represent the string to be replaced and the string to replace it with, respectively.
- `environment` is a string containing exactly 1 underscore (`_`), representing the substitution, and any number of letters and category names, representing the required context for the substitution to take place. It can also contain the `#` character, representing the beginning or end of a word.

Some examples, assuming the `V` category from earlier:

```
ii/i/_    Change ii to i anywhere in a word
i/j/_V    Change i to j when followed by a vowel
u/o/_#    Change u to o at the end of a word
p//V_t    Delete p if preceded by a vowel and followed by t
```

#### Categories in substitutions

When category names are used in the environment, the environment matches if any member of the category is in the appropriate place. For example, the last rule above will delete the `p` from `apt`, `opt`, `inept`, or `scripting`, but not from `thbpt`.

The same is true when categories are used in the target but not the replacement. For example, the rule `V/e/Vr_#` will delete any vowel if it matches the environment: `opera` -> `oper`, `sombrero` -> `sombrer`, `calamari` -> `calamar` (but not `cobra` -> `cobr` because the environment vowel isn't matched).

However, if categories are used in both the target and replacement, the replacement letter must come from the same position in its category as the matched target letter does in its category.

For example, suppose we have these category definitions: `S=ptc`, `Z=bdg`. (These are [unvoiced and voiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)) [stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant), respectively.) Then the substitution `S/Z/V_V` (changed unvoiced stops to voiced between vowels) represents three possible substitutions: `p` -> `b`, `t` -> `d`, and `c` -> `g`.

#### Execution

An SCA program accepts as input a list of words to be transformed. It goes down the list of substitutions in order, applying each one to all words in the word list. Each substitution is applied repeatedly until the environment and/or target no longer matches. Then the next substitution is applied. When all substitutions have completed, the program outputs the transformed list of words.

#### Miscellaneous rules

If a category is used in the replacement, a category must also be used in the target.

The replacement may be empty, but the target may not be empty.

Category names, letters, and words in the word list will never use the characters `=/#_` or space.

### The challenge

Write a program or function that takes an SCA program and a list of words and outputs/returns the result of running that program on those words.

You may assume that the SCA program is syntactically valid and that the words do not contain any forbidden characters. If these assumptions are broken, your code may do anything (handle it gracefully, crash, output gibberish).

#### I/O format

Input format is flexible. You may take the program as a multiline string or a list of strings. The category definitions and substitutions may be in the same string/list or two different strings/lists (or contained in a two-item list). The input words may be in a list or a space- or newline-delimited string. Similarly, output may be a list or a space- or newline-delimited string.

Any of the [default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/16766) are acceptable. You may use different input methods for category definitions, substitutions, and input words if it makes the task easier in your language.

Linguists use [many letter forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) that are not present in ASCII. Therefore, your program **must** be able to accept Unicode characters up through **U+1FFF** (at least) in both the rules and the word list.

### Example

Adapted from Mark Rosenfelder's site, here is a simplistic Latin-to-Portuguese converter.

Categories:

```
V=aeiou
L=āēīōū
C=ptcqbdgmnlrhs     
F=ie
B=ou
S=ptc
Z=bdg
```

Substitutions:

```
m//_#
i/j/_V
L/V/_
e//Vr_#
v//V_V
u/o/_#
gn/nh/_
S/Z/V_V
c/i/F_t
c/u/B_t
p//V_t
ii/i/_
e//C_rV
lj/lh/_
```

Given the following input list:

```
lēctōrem
doctōrem
focum
jocum
districtum
cīvitātem
adoptāre
opera
secundum
fīliam
pontem
```

the output list should be as follows:

```
leitor
doutor
fogo
jogo
distrito
cidade
adotar
obra
segundo
filha
ponte
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); the shortest code wins.

Comment: "Sound Change Applier" is so XKCD thing-explainer style! Although I admit it might not be a good fit here on PPCG. As for the challenge itself, I'd say, try to make it a bit more clear, have explicit definitions for all the important words you pick, so that there is no confusion on what counts as substitution and what doesn't, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

## Output every string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task here is simple. Write a program, in as few bytes as possible, which prints every single possible string. Your program should, given infinite memory, never terminate, however for any given string there should be a finite time to be generated. (that is, a aa aaa aaaa ... Won't work as it will never generate b).

The strings to be generated should consist of all the characters in the same encoding as your answer, which you must specify if not utf-8.

The exception is that you must choose a character to exclude from your strings, which you will use to delimit strings. You may optionally have one leading delimiter.

Remember to include the empty string!

Comment: I think this would be a duplicate of [output all strings](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74273/20260).

Comment: @xnor that one takes input, this one just encompasses every possible string. I think it's worth having a challenge for that.

Comment: I disagree here: the new part is generating one of every character (except a separator), which I don't think merits a new challenge.

Answer (score 0):

### The many errors of twin primes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)

---

> **Note:** this is a repost of my [earlier challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45584/recognize-twin-primes-by-crashing), but with a different winning condition and better rules.

### Background

Bob was handed the following assignment for his programming class (this is not the actual challenge).

> **Homework assignment 11: Twin primes**
>
> Take as input an integer **n ≥ 8** and print a single character, depending on **n**:
>
> - If **n** is not a prime number, print `N` for "Not prime".
> - If **n** is a prime number, but neither of **n - 2** and **n + 2** is, print `I` for "Isolated prime".
> - If **n** and **n + 2** are both prime numbers, print `L` for "Lower twin prime".
> - If **n** and **n - 2** are both prime numbers, print `U` for "Upper twin prime".

Bob tried hard to solve the assignment, but his program kept crashing, and in the end, he gave up and submitted it in hope of partial credit. Nevertheless, Bob's program has the curious property that even though it never does what it's supposed to, the input is still classified correctly depending on the program's behavior: non-primes result in no output, isolated primes in a crash, lower twin primes in an infinite loop with no output, and upper twin primes in an infinite loop that keeps printing the correct message.

### The Task

Your task is to replicate the behavior or Bob's solution: you shall write a program or function that behaves as follows.
Your input is a single integer **n ≥ 8**.

1. If **n** is not a prime number, print nothing and exit gracefully.
2. If **n** is a prime number, but none of **n - 2** or **n + 2** is, print nothing and exit with a runtime error of some kind (like stack overflow or division by 0).
3. If **n** and **n + 2** are both prime numbers, print nothing and keep running indefinitely (or until you run out of memory).
4. If **n** and **n - 2** are both prime numbers, repeatedly print the character `U` to STDOUT indefinitely (or until you run out of memory). The output can contain newlines, commas or other separators.

Input can be taken with any of our [default methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), but all output *must* go to STDOUT (and STDERR in case of error) or closest alternative.

The lowest byte count wins.

### Test cases

```
8 -> [no output]
9 -> [no output]
10 -> [no output]
11 -> [infinite loop]
12 -> [no output]
13 -> UUUUUUUUU[continues indefinitely]
14 -> [no output]
15 -> [no output]
16 -> [no output]
17 -> [infinite loop]
18 -> [no output]
19 -> UUUUUUUUU[continues indefinitely]
20 -> [no output]
21 -> [no output]
22 -> [no output]
23 -> [runtime error]
29 -> [infinite loop]
31 -> UUUUUUUUU[continues indefinitely]
37 -> [runtime error]
```

---

### Sandbox notes

To keep the rules simple, I decided to only allow output to STDOUT.

Comment: that's not really simplifying? couldn't you allow functions, but mandate output through stdout and stderr?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Yeah, that's actually much more reasonable.

Comment: Would it not be better to edit the previous question and try to get it reopened?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ideally, yes. But it has existing answers, which are not competitive at all in a pure golf context. Won't that be an issue?

Comment: Hmm. I noticed that golfing was taken into account in the previous scoring system, but I didn't notice that 2 out of the 3 answers didn't golf. I retract my previous suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## Arrange ranges of numbers in columns

Write a program to print from *m* to input *n* with step *s*, arranging the numbers in either horizontal or vertical columns.

### Clarifications

- You can use any two values, or kinds of values, for signifying horizontal and vertical columns, specifying these in your answer.

### Test cases

```
from:
m = 1, n = 15, s = 1, vertical columns
to:
         111111
123456789012345

from:
m = 1, n = 11, s = 2, horizontal columns
to:
1
3
5
7
9
11

from:
m = 1, n = 11, s = 2, vertical columns
to:
     1
135791
```

> Any more clarifications or test cases?

*This challenge is based on a [chat mini challenge by Helka Homba](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24690794#24690794), which is allowed to be used in real challenges under the conditions of [Calvin's Hobbies Public License](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=27296595#27296595)*.

Answer (score 0):

## [Natural Order Sorting](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Natural_sort_order)

**Goal** :: Writing a sorting algorithm that doesn't need preceding zeroes to sort music files properly.

Natural Order Sorting will be defined in this way:

- **Consecutive Digits** (ie `[0-9]+`) are considered one character and its value is the evaluation of those digits as an integer (eg `int("0123")`)
- **Uppercase Letters** (ie `[A-Z]`) are each their own character and its value is the ASCII value of the letter
- **Lowercase Letters** (ie `[a-z]`) are each their own character and its value is the corresponding uppercase value plus `.5`
- **Symbols** (ie `[^0-z]`) are each their own character and its value is the ASCII value of the symbol
- **Symbols** are always before **Digits** which are always before **Letters**
- If two characters are in the same category, the one with the small value precedes the other

### Specification

- **Input** :: An unordered list of strings (flexible on how)
- **Output** :: A list of strings that are naturally ordered (flexible on how)
- **Victory** :: Shortest program/function in bytes, wins

### Test Cases

```
Input                             Output
-----                             ------
10,11,8,9                      -> 8,9,10,11
appleA,CiderB,AppleC           -> AppleC,appleA,CiderB
File1,File12,File143A,File031B -> File1,File2,File031B,File143A
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Flip-Flop Program

Your challenge is simple: write a *full program* which alternates between two different outputs upon each run.

Your submission can choose which is printed the first time the program is run, but after that it should alternate between these *exact* outputs.

### Rules/Details

- You cannot assume the filename of your program.
- The values must be distinct.
- Creating files is allowed - you are allowed to assume a file such as `a.txt` does not already exist in the directory.
- Reading and modifying the source is allowed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the **shortest solution (in bytes) wins**! Standard golfing loopholes apply.

### Sandbox

- Should I allow assuming the program's filename at an additional bytecount (length of filename)?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stateful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stateful)

Comment: Is it neccessary that the first run always produces the same value? (That makes the problem considerably harder, because it requires detecting the first run.) I agree with the full program restriction here, btw; it avoids a lot of dubious rules-bending answers that change something in the execution state.

Comment: If you want to be *really crazy*, you can do something like `main(){int n = 1` *Then change n in the compiled file* `return n;}`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman is this an explanation of the downvote or was that someone else?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman see update.

Comment: Why the full program requirement? As far as I can tell, it will be very hard to do this with just functions. Why disallow something that could give interesting answers? Programs would likely just change their own source code, or read a value from a file and then change it (or append a new one).

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107642/42963).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork would you say that it's too similar?

Comment: Personally, I think they're distinct enough to not be a duplicate, they're just definitely related.

Comment: I didn't downvote since to me this looked fairly good besides what felt like an arbitrary restriction that would just make gaming the challenge easier. Also, I remembered another [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38084/31625), for reference.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that's why I recently helped add the [tag:stateful] tag, all similar challenges involving storing data between runs and self-modifying code are gradually being added there

Answer (score 0):

### Source code standard deviation

Your program should accept as input a string, convert it to a unsigned byte array using UTF-8 encoding and output the standard deviation of the `n` bytes.

Standard deviation is given by this formula, where `x1`...`xn` are the string's bytes:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/1/8/31830fa1f2f922edf6079209a51f8967.png]

**Example**

Input `hello`:

- UTF-8 encoding returns the list `[104,101,108,108,111]`
- mean is `106.4`
- standard deviation is `3.49857113690718`

More test cases:

- `ppcg`: 5.678908345800274
- `aaaaa`: 0
- `azazaz`: 12.5
- `smiley☺`: 41.12432220162674

**Scoring**

Your score is the standard deviation of your source code, using the above algorithm, divided by the length of your source in bytes, using UTF-8 encoding. **The higher the better**.

For example, the score for the program `hello` is: 3.49857113690718 / 5 = 0.699714227381436

Related: [Calculate Standard Deviation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60901/calculate-standard-deviation)

Comment: Programs can pad their standard deviation by including a huge number of the highest and lowest possible character in equal amounts in a comment.

Comment: @xnor yes, but after some time, the score decreases when adding these characters. For example, `hello` scores 0.69, `hello ÿ` scores 6.15, `hello ÿ ÿ` scores 5.31.

Comment: I see you now this doesn't raise your score arbitrarily, though [the numbers I'm getting are different](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@ZW5BfVKJQXJJYkllckplczMWVkpoG5BfFp6SWaRRrWnEpAEGObXR@UYpGhaZCWn6RQoVCZp5CcSxYpii1pLQoD8kAveISkM4cTf2c1DwgxcVVUJSZV6IBM1IpIzUnJ19JUxOruMLh/XikILL//wMA).

Comment: @xnor I think you need to use `statistics.pstdev`, not `statistics.stdev`

Comment: So an answer in Unary is guaranteed to score 0?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes, an answer in Unary is guaranteed to lose, as the higher score the better.

Comment: @SuperChafouin I see. Putting in `pstdev` still gives different numbers from yours.

Comment: `ÿ` is interpreted by the python command `ord` as integer 255 - while it should be the two bytes [`0xC3 0xBF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

## Prime Factors that Weren't there Before

Given a list of integers `a`, calculate the prime factorization for each integer in the array. Then, return a list of factors that do not appear in the original input, even as part of another number. For instance, if you were given:

`a = [1243,11311]`

The prime factors would be calculated as:

`a' = [[11, 113], [11311]] = []`

Because `11 appears in 11311`, and `113 appears in 11311`, the result would be `[]`, an empty set.

---

Lets look at another example:

`a = [270,325,192] = [[2, 3, 3, 3, 5], [5, 5, 13], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]] = [13]`

---

Another example:

`a  = [27072,32585,19296]
a'  = [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 47], [5, 7, 7, 7, 19], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 67]]
a'' = [47,67]`

---

A bigger example:

`a   = [56,3924,10000,1240124]`
`a'  = [[2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 3, 3, 109], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 31, 73, 137]]`
`a'' = [7,109,31,73,137]`

This is code golf, lowest byte-count wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Contiguous Palindromic Subsequencing

Given a word `a`, perform the following operations:

1. Group string into palindromic subsequences of length > 2 and non-palindromic subsequences. (You should prioritize partition length over partition index, for instance `esse` shouldn't result in `['e','ss','e']`, it should be `['esse']`. However, if the lengths are the same for two subsequences, use index to prioritize which you choose).
2. Make all non-palindromic subsequences palindromic (single characters are palindromic here).
3. Put it back together.

You may assume only printable ASCII characters are used.

---

## Examples:

`raggamuffin -> ['r','agga','muffin'] -> ['r','agga','muffiniffum'] -> raggamuffiniffum`

`bananaracecar -> ['b','anana','racecar'] -> ['b','anana','racecar'] -> Unchanged.`

(Since each palindrome grouping would be the same length, use the first one).
SIZE OF GROUP > INDEX OF GROUP
`abaca -> ['aba', 'ca'] -> ['aba','cac'] -> abacac`

(Always choose the bigger palindrome, THEN go by index)
`cheesewheels -> ['che','ese','wh','ee','ls'] -> ['chehc','ese','whw','ee','lsl'] -> chehcesewhweelsl`

(Always choose the bigger palindrome, THEN go by index)
`1223224 -> [1,22322,4] -> Unchanged.`

`abbabbababbababba -> ['a', 'bb', 'abbababbababba'] -> Unchanged.`

`abcdefg -> ['abcdefg'] -> ['abcdefgfedcba'] -> abcdefgfedcba`

`slammedintoacardoor -> ['sla', 'mm', 'edinto', 'aca', 'rd', 'oo', 'r'] -> ['slals', 'mm', 'edintotnide', 'aca', 'rdr', 'oo', 'r'] -> slalsmmedeintotniacardroor`

`eeefffgegffhi -> ['eee','f','ffgegff','hi'] -> ['eee','f','ffgegff','hih'] -> eeefffgegffhih`

---

This will be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: The term "subsequence" doesn't usually imply that they are contiguous. `ac` is a subsequence of `abc`. You should either use "substring" or "contiguous subsequence" to avoid confusion.

Comment: I can't tell whether this is covered by any of your test cases, but it's also not explicitly mentioned in the rules, what about a test case like `abaca`. Is it `ab,aca` or `aba,ca`, since the palindromes have the same length? What about `abacada`? `aba,c,ada`? `ab,aca,da`?

Comment: Also, string challenges should specify which characters can appear in the input.

Comment: In test case `slammedintoacardoor`, shouldn't `ed` and `into` be combined into one substring?

Comment: @MartinEnder I worded it wrong, you should be prioritizing length of substring, THEN position. So it would be `aba,ca`.

Comment: @Zgarb yes, you're right.

Comment: @MartinEnder `aba,c,ada` because `aba` is before both `aca` and `ada` using index. Then `ada` and `c` are what would be prioritized to be grouped next.

Answer (score 0):

## Play time

Hello. It is time to play the most popular portuguese card game: [Sueca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sueca_(card_game))! So for people who does not know the game, it is needed to print a wall poster to make them know the power and the points each card has.

So, the job is to print an ASCII art wall as:

```
    11        10        4         3         2        ———       ———       ———       ———       ———
   
╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ 
|A     A| |7     7| |R     R| |V     V| |D     D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥    /♥| |♥    /♥| |♥    /♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| 
|       | |  ♥ ♥  | | ♔ /  | | ♗ /  | |  ♕ /  | |  ♥ ♥  | |  ♥ ♥  | |  ♥ ♥  | |       | |   ♥   | 
|   ♥   | |   ♥   | |   /   | |   /   | |   /   | |  ♥ ♥  | |   ♥   | |       | |  ♥ ♥  | |       | 
|       | |  ♥ ♥  | |  / ♔ | |  / ♗ | |  / ♕  | |  ♥ ♥  | |  ♥ ♥  | |  ♥ ♥  | |   ♥   | |   ♥   | 
|A     A| |7 ♥ ♥ 7| |R/    R| |V/    V| |D/    D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| |♥     ♥| 
╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ 
   
╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ 
|A     A| |7     7| |R     R| |V     V| |D     D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦    /♦| |♦    /♦| |♦    /♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| 
|       | |  ♦ ♦  | | ♔ /  | | ♗ /  | |  ♕ /  | |  ♦ ♦  | |  ♦ ♦  | |  ♦ ♦  | |       | |   ♦   | 
|   ♦   | |   ♦   | |   /   | |   /   | |   /   | |  ♦ ♦  | |   ♦   | |       | |  ♦ ♦  | |       | 
|       | |  ♦ ♦  | |  / ♔ | |  / ♗ | |   / ♕ | |  ♦ ♦  | |  ♦ ♦  | |  ♦ ♦  | |   ♦   | |   ♦   | 
|A     A| |7 ♦ ♦ 7| |R/    R| |V/    V| |D/    D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| |♦     ♦| 
╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯
   
╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ 
|A     A| |7     7| |R     R| |V     V| |D     D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣    /♣| |♣    /♣| |♣    /♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| 
|       | |  ♣ ♣  | | ♚ /  | | ♝ /  | |  ♛ /  | |  ♣ ♣  | |  ♣ ♣  | |  ♣ ♣  | |       | |   ♣   | 
|   ♣   | |   ♣   | |   /   | |   /   | |   /   | |  ♣ ♣  | |   ♣   | |       | |  ♣ ♣  | |       | 
|       | |  ♣ ♣  | |  / ♚ | |  / ♝ | |  / ♛  | |  ♣ ♣  | |  ♣ ♣  | |  ♣ ♣  | |   ♣   | |   ♣   | 
|A     A| |7 ♣ ♣ 7| |R/    R| |V/    V| |D/    D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| |♣     ♣| 
╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ 
   
╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ ╭───────╮ 
|A     A| |7     7| |R     R| |V     V| |D     D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠    /♠| |♠    /♠| |♠    /♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| 
|       | |  ♠ ♠  | | ♚ /  | |  ♝/  | |  ♛ /  | |  ♠ ♠  | |  ♠ ♠  | |  ♠ ♠  | |       | |   ♠   | 
|   ♠   | |   ♠   | |   /   | |   /   | |   /   | |  ♠ ♠  | |   ♠   | |       | |  ♠ ♠  | |       | 
|       | |  ♠ ♠  | |  / ♚ | |  / ♝ | |  / ♛  | |  ♠ ♠  | |  ♠ ♠  | |  ♠ ♠  | |   ♠   | |   ♠   | 
|A     A| |7 ♠ ♠ 7| |R/    R| |V/    V| |D/    D| |6     6| |5     5| |4     4| |3     3| |2     2| 
|♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| |♠     ♠| 
╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯ ╰───────╯
```

Comment: You should specify which specific characters should be used. Of note, several of the ones you used don't appear to fall in the ASCII range.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: Should I call it Unicode Art?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman If you know better chars than ♔♗♕ ♚ ♝ ♛ for me to put in the question, please tell me. I don't like the effect they have on the white space width after them.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any better characters, but yes, that would be less confusing. I still think adding the exact character codes would be a good idea.

Comment: The "ascii-art" looks aweful in my browser (firefox on win): https://i.stack.imgur.com/keYgN.jpg

Comment: @flawr: In mine (Vivaldi on Windows) they look better: http://i.imgur.com/OIILDbB.png but not perfectly drawn; it is due to the chess Unicode characters. I am waiting for opinions on better characters, please. The queen card (D) seems a lot the King card! The Jack (V) doesn't even seem to be a Jack! And the King (R) also does not seem the King!

Answer (score 0):

## Left-to-Right calculator

Given the opinion I posted on https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/99984/51560 , I want to have a calculator where the least-significant least digits are placed on the left.

The input must come from stdin. It only needs to support non-negative integers. Additions must support any number of parcels, and to end the input of parcels input an empty line. In every example, all above the first ——— line is input, the first ——— line itself and the lines below are output.

Example:

```
+
2134
254
89
————
0684
```

Subtractions input is always composed by two operators:

```
-
3351547
945613
———————
4894317
```

Multiplications input is also two operands.Must support at multiplications where the second operator is < 100 and output the auxiliary addition like the way it is done by hand.

```
*
94651
74
———————
345901
 69526
———————
305537
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1 line ASCII Domino play

The game is described on my own question I posted on [Domino game maximum achievable points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091748/domino-game-maximum-achievable-points).

The rules for scoring are on the link, and I am reposting them here:

> The rules for scoring are: every time a part is placed, if the sum of
>   both ends of the dominoes chain is a multiple of 5, you add it to you
>   current score.
>
> example: [4|2] [2|1] makes 5 points
>
> A double (every part where the two halfes are equal) is always placed
>   rotated by 90º; so for accounting purposes, unlike other pieces, both
>   sides ot the part are taken into account.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ___       ___
> |6|       |4|
> ——— [6|4] ———  
> |6|       |4|
> ———       ———
> ```
>
> makes for 20 points.
>
> One single part placed accounts as the two tips.
>
> Example [2|3] accounts as 5 points
>
> And
>
> ```
> ___ 
> |5| 
> ——— 
> |5| 
> ———  accounts as 10 points.
> ```

The challenge is to write a game that is an ASCII one line domino game for me to play.

Rules:

- You must output to stderr/stdout
- Line Width is 80 chars
- The first two chars are reserved for displaying points, aligned at right. By definition, it will always be a multiple of 5; and the third is always a  space
- Given space is limited:

  - Every join of two parts will conjoin and they will be separed by a `|` they will share instead of `][`
  - Double parts (those where the two halves are equal) will be represented abbreviate:

    - [ | ] => [ ]
    - [1|1] => [=]
    - [2|2] => [+]
    - [3|3] => [*]
    - [4|4] => [&]
    - [5|5] => [X]
    - [6|6] => [%]
  - Except for white double, all whites are represented by only the other half
  - Every other part is represented by [NM], where N and M are the number of each half
- The ends of the whole dominoes chain are always terminated by []
- The initial state is an empty table. First piece placed will be at the center
- When chain begins to not fit, at one of the ends, it must be adjusted to fit by pushing the whole placing a little bit to the left or the right.
- The last 3 chars of the line are reserved for user input. User can only input a piece not yet placed. User input is `NM` which is displayed; and a keypress of `+` or `-` which will **NOT** be displayed to avoid a newline feed. The key press tells what side of the chain will the new piece will be snapped:

  - `-` to left
  - `+` to right
  - It also must validate the snapping. If user snaps to a non-matching piece, just do nothing. The program will **NOT** be smart enough to make guesses; so it will **NOT** make a piece to snap on the other side if piece does not match user specified side
  - And after each valid placing of a piece, must update the points display if there are some to score.

Example of an **INVALID** placed chain, containing a sequence which would not be possible, because there are pieces snapped to not-matching pieces.

```
  5 [ |=|+|*|&|X|%|1|2|3|4|5|6|12|13|14|15|16|23|24|25|26|34|35|36|45|46|56] 12{+}
```

The `{+}` is not displayed, it is there just to illustrate the input:

Comment: I find this rather confusing. After reading it three times I think I begin to understand the spec, but 1. Why those random characters for the doubles? IMO `!@#$%&` would be preferable: it's easy to refer to for people with a US-layout keyboard, and it corresponds to the ASCII characters at an offset of 32 from the digits. 2. What's all that about `][`? The question should be self-contained: don't confuse things by assuming that people have read another related question. 3. Following on from that, you should explain the scoring.

Comment: 4. Don't give an example of an invalid chain: the example which would be actually useful is a valid chain. 5. Doesn't the abbreviated form for 0s create ambiguities? If the board is currently `[6]` then which is valid out of `46-`, `46+`, `64-`, `64+`, `4-`, `4+`? 6. What's the initial state? Empty board, and either of `-` or `+` does the same thing?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Those chars have been decided on the appearance they have. `=` seems [11] rotated vertically; `+` being a four-point star is the most similar I get to [22]; the same goes for `*` as it is a 6 point star; `&` seems an 8, which are the points of [44]; `X` is an way to say 10, which are the number points of a [55]; `%` seems to have a 10 and a 2 number implicit on it, as the slash and final ball seem a 10, and the existent balls are two, then twelve which are the points of [66].

Comment: Given the space is limited, the joining of two pieces must conjoin, so `][` becomes `|` to save space. Example: [23][34] becomes [23|34]

Comment: Reproduced *ipsis verbis* from the link the rules for scoring.

Comment: @trichoplax: It is clearly stated: "User can only input a piece not yet placed". There are only 28 dominoes and the statement makes clear there are no repetitions. I am already getting issues trying to put the whole chain in only one line and you want to make the problem even worse?!

Comment: @PeterTaylor :Just made clear `The initial state is an empty table`

Comment: @trichoplax: I upvoted your comment: `Is there a missing second half of sentence after "When chain begins to not fit"?`.Sentence is now fixed!

Comment: My apologies for overlooking "User can only input a piece not yet placed". I've deleted both my comments now that they have been addressed.

Comment: @trichoplax: I made now clear the program will not have any kind of "smartness". So if user specifies 64- and left side is not a 4, placing is simply rejected.

Answer (score 0):

### Graphical Borromean Rings

Here is an SVG rendering of the [Borromean Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="green">
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="70%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#0F0" offset="75%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#CFC" offset="85%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#0F0" offset="95%"/>
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="blue">
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="70%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#00F" offset="75%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#CCF" offset="85%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#00F" offset="95%"/>
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="red">
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="70%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#F00" offset="75%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#FCC" offset="85%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#F00" offset="95%"/>
      <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <mask height="100" width="100" y="0" x="0" id="back">
      <rect fill="#FFF" height="100" width="50" y="0" x="0"/>
      <rect fill="#FFF" height="50" width="50" y="25" x="50"/>
    </mask>
    <mask height="100" width="100" y="0" x="0" id="front">
      <rect fill="#FFF" height="25" width="50" y="0" x="50"/>
      <rect fill="#FFF" height="25" width="50" y="75" x="50"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle mask="url(#back)" fill="url(#green)" r="50" cy="50" cx="50"/>
  <circle fill="url(#blue)" r="50" cy="93.3" cx="75"/>
  <circle fill="url(#red)" r="50" cy="50" cx="100"/>
  <circle mask="url(#front)" fill="url(#green)" r="50" cy="50" cx="50"/>
</svg>
```

Please write a full program to generate a [graphical-image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-image) which resembles the above rendering reasonably well. In particular:

- Solid colours, aliased pixels or overlap artefacts are not acceptable
- Your colours should contrast with each other
- Your circles must default to at least 100px in diameter (I wanted larger circles in my snippet but I get a scroll bar if I try)
- Your circles must have the appearance of overlapping impossibly
- Rotations and reflections are perfectly acceptable

Output is via any generally acceptable output format e.g. writing to vector or raster image format or displaying directly to the screen. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins.

Related: [ASCII Borromean Rings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53417/ascii-borromean-rings)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18986/16766). [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19050/16766).

Comment: @DLosc Well, those are interlocking rings... Borromean rings don't interlock in pairs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## Number that includes the amount of digits of itself

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Create a number where each digit represents the amount of this digit the number itself contains. Maybe my english is too bad to describe it clearly so here is an example:

```
6210001000
explanation:
6               -> this number contains 6 times '0'
 2              -> this number contains 2 times '1'
  1             -> this number contains 1 time  '2'
   0            -> this number contains 0 times '3'
    0           -> this number contains 0 times '4'
     0          -> this number contains 0 times '5'
      1         -> this number contains 1 time  '6'
       0        -> this number contains 0 times '7'
        0       -> this number contains 0 times '8'
         0      -> this number contains 0 times '9'
```

We will call those numbers self-describing. Each self-describing number must be 10 digits long to be able to represent all digits from 0 to 9.

I have two possible goals for this challenge:

1. Create a program which prints out all self-describing numbers in the range `0000000000 < X < 99999999999`
2. For a given integer in the range `0000000000 < X < 99999999999` print out `true` if it's a self-describing number, else `false`.

I can add further examples and rules if i move it out of the sandbox.

Comment: @Fatalize Yes my bad i will search for a correct number

Comment: "*I can add further examples*": no, you can't. That's the only one. If you want to get an interesting question out of this you're going to have to open it up to other bases.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51264/62131). [Also related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100705/62131).

Answer (score 0):

## Digit stream with no 42

You should write a program or function which receives no input and outputs a stream of digits.

- The stream should contain at least once every positive integer number which does not contain the digit sequence `42`. E.g. The string `1231` contains the integers `1 12 123 1231 2 23 231 3 31 (and 1 again)`
- The stream should *not* contain the digit sequence `42`.
- If your interpreter can't handle infinite output gracefully you can add code to only print the first `n` digits. This added code does not count to your score.
- Note that the stream `203204205...` contains `42`.
- No randomness should be used.

This is code-golf so the shortest entry wins.

*Do we have infinite output tag?*

Comment: I think you need to say something about random numbers. Either require that the program always outputs the same stream or be very specific about requirements on the RNG for an answer which outputs random digits avoiding `2` when the previous one was a `4`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right, forbidding randomness is probably the cleanest solution. Showing whether an RNG-using code solves the problem seems pretty complex.

Comment: So a program that always prints 1234567890 will satisfy this, or am I missing something?

Comment: @carusocomputing The stream should contain every **integer** not just every digit. E.g. `1234567891011121314...` fulfills this point.

Answer (score 0):

### Rainbow Cat Program

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Recently, I remembered a program I'd written in C# a while back for fun. It takes a string as input, then outputs that same string, cycling through a rainbow of colours. I now realize that this is basically a [cat program](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cat_program), but with the added complexity of the output changing colour every 100ms. So I figured it would make an interesting challenge.

The aim is to make your own "rainbow cat program", taking a string as input, and outputting that same string cycling through the following colours in sequence: **red, yellow, green, blue, purple**, and **pink**. Not quite a proper rainbow, but close enough. The colours must change **every 100ms** (or as close to 100ms as your chosen language will allow).

For reference, here's an extremely badly-golfed version of my original C# program **(370 bytes)**:

```
using System;using System.Threading;class P{static void Main(){var a=Console.ReadLine();for(;;){L(a,ConsoleColor.Red);L(a,ConsoleColor.Yellow);L(a,ConsoleColor.Green);L(a,ConsoleColor.Blue);L(a,ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta);L(a,ConsoleColor.Magenta);}}static void L(string a,ConsoleColor b){Console.Clear();Console.ForegroundColor=b;Console.WriteLine(a);Thread.Sleep(100);}}
```

And a gif of it in action!

[image]

## Other Rules

- Trailing whitespace/newlines are allowed; printing so many newlines that you push the text off the screen, then writing it again in the next colour, is not allowed. You must physically clear the screen and rewrite the text rather than writing it out over and over.
- Once the cycle starts, it should continue indefinitely without any user input.
- Standard golfing loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program wins. Feel free to compete for the shortest program in any given language, though: don't feel put off by the golfing languages!

Answer (score 0):

## Where am I?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)(Some other tags pls help)

Your task in this challenge is to output the location of the user. This may be done by means of GeoIP, a builtin GPS device, or any other means. Output should either be in the format (latitude, longitude) accurate to at least one degree, or (City, [optional state/province/etc], Country). Errors due to the GPS device being inaccurate or similar which are not the fault of your code are allowed. Fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Accurate to one degree? Holy hell, do you know how much one degree is? https://www.google.com/maps/dir/11.00000,+2.000000/10,1/@10.4729646,0.8176501,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d2!2d11!1m0

Comment: Also, this is more or less "output the location of the users ISP"...

Comment: @carusocomputing one degree of Latitude/Longitude. That's just 11, 2.

Comment: I was just pointing out that if you look at 10,1 compared to 11,2 it's in a different country. If you say closest to the nearest degree the answers will not be constant.

Comment: @carusocomputing Oh, I misunderstood. I know 1 degree is a lot, but I think it's good enough. It requires actually finding the location rather than relying on other information, which is all that's really needed. This way could cut out some code necessary for formatting which isn't part of the challenge.

Comment: Ping the router. Ask the router where it is. Done. (No idea if this would work)

Answer (score 0):

## Do you accept me?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

### Introduction

Being accepted is very important to people. But words are also people (right!?). So they also want to be accepted. However most people work non-deterministically and as such it's only fair to transfer that into our decision whether we accept a word. Of course, because a stupid human can't remember much the instructions to decide whether to accept a word must be short...

### Input

Your input will be

- a list of non-negative integers - the "word" (this is easier than using strings and actual alphabets)
- a list of triples of non-negative integers - the transitions, you may also use unordered data structures here
- an integer - the starting state
- a list of non-negative integers - the accepting states, you may also use unordered data structures here

You may use any other object or whatever than integers if it pleases you.

### Output

A truthy or a falsey value.

### What to do?

Basically implement an NFA.
That is, read every single character (ie every number) from left to right and for each one of them look whether there exist a transition from your current state using this character. If so follow it and repeat the process for the next letter. If you face an empty list, your current state must be in the list of accepted states if it is output true and stop examining other paths if it isn't continue examining the other options. If you get stuck  (ie the word isn't empty but there's no way to continue), output false.

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Examples

For the following examples I'm going to use this automaton:
[image: Example NFA]

which has starting state `10`, accepting states `[13]` and transitions

```
[(10,4,11),
(11,4,11),
(11,1,12),
(12,1,12),
(12,3,13),
(13,3,13),
(11,3,13)]
```

These three parameters are assumed to be also passed in the examples. Word examples for this automaton are:

```
[1,2,3,4] -> false
[4,1,3,4] -> false
[4,1,3] -> true
[4,1,3,3,3] -> true
[2,1,3,4,3,2] -> false
[4,1,4] -> false
[4,3,1] -> false
[4,3,3] -> true
```

Comment: I'm aware of [this other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11012/55329) but truly believe that mine is different enough because a) it uses relations instead of a function b) it only asks for NFAs and not for three different automatons c) it asks for truthy / false instead of hard-coded strings d) it's not limited to strings e) it doesn't assume an implicit starting state.

Answer (score 0):

## Simulate a vibrating string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Vibrations are an integral part of physics.  In this challenge, you will be implementing a simulation of a vibrating string.

This is actually rather easy to do as a result of the [Huygens–Fresnel principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle), which allows us to use a simulation process similar to cellular automata.

(don't have time to write a full spec right now.  Also, I have a 2D version working but figured 1D was enough for a challenge)

Below is an example of a string vibrating at its second harmonic, with each row being 1 tick of the simulation.

```
  1.00  2.00  1.00 -1.00 -2.00 -1.00
  0.95  1.90  0.95 -0.95 -1.90 -0.95
  0.85  1.70  0.85 -0.85 -1.70 -0.85
  0.71  1.42  0.71 -0.71 -1.42 -0.71
  0.54  1.07  0.54 -0.54 -1.07 -0.54
  0.33  0.67  0.33 -0.33 -0.67 -0.33
  0.11  0.23  0.11 -0.11 -0.23 -0.11
 -0.11 -0.22 -0.11  0.11  0.22  0.11
 -0.33 -0.66 -0.33  0.33  0.66  0.33
 -0.53 -1.07 -0.53  0.53  1.07  0.53
 -0.71 -1.42 -0.71  0.71  1.42  0.71
 -0.85 -1.70 -0.85  0.85  1.70  0.85
 -0.95 -1.90 -0.95  0.95  1.90  0.95
 -1.00 -2.00 -1.00  1.00  2.00  1.00
```

This challenge is based off the math found on [this website](http://www.mtnmath.com/whatrh/node66.html).

Answer (score 0):

## loripsum.net

The purpose of this challenge is to emulate the functionality of the loripsum.net website. This website takes in a "number of paragraphs" and a list of randomized HTML5 stylizations and outputs a pre-formatted HTML5 lorem ipsum text that is REALLY good for placeholders on a prototype website. Your code, however, will focus more on the stylization aspect of this website.

---

Given a block of lorem ipsum text in the following format:

`<segment> := <paragraph> | <paragraph><new-line><segment>`

`<paragraph> := <sentence> | <sentence><paragraph>`

`<sentence> := <character_run><sentence_end>`

`<character_run> := <printable_ascii_without_newline_or_period>|<pawnop><character_run>`

`<sentence_end> := \n | . | ? | !`

---

Here's an example of a possible input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quonam,
>   inquit, modo? Progredientibus autem aetatibus sensim tardeve potius
>   quasi nosmet ipsos cognoscimus. Quod non faceret, si in voluptate
>   summum bonum poneret. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
>
> Tubulo putas dicere? Cum salvum esse flentes sui respondissent,
>   rogavit essentne fusi hostes. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat. Satisne
>   ergo pudori consulat, si quis sine teste libidini pareat? Negare non
>   possum. An hoc usque quaque, aliter in vita? Plane idem, inquit, et
>   maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest. Quid ei reliquisti, nisi
>   te, quoquo modo loqueretur, intellegere, quid diceret?
>
> Itaque ad tempus ad Pisonem omnes. Universa enim illorum ratione cum
>   tota vestra confligendum puto. Haec dicuntur inconstantissime. Dicimus
>   aliquem hilare vivere; Qui non moveatur et offensione turpitudinis et
>   comprobatione honestatis? Sed quot homines, tot sententiae; Quippe:
>   habes enim a rhetoribus; Omnes enim iucundum motum, quo sensus
>   hilaretur. Tria genera bonorum; Profectus in exilium Tubulus statim
>   nec respondere ausus;
>
> Certe non potest. Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam
>   Epicurus; Graece donan, Latine voluptatem vocant. Itaque a sapientia
>   praecipitur se ipsam, si usus sit, sapiens ut relinquat. Quid est
>   igitur, inquit, quod requiras? Atque haec coniunctio confusioque
>   virtutum tamen a philosophis ratione quadam distinguitur. Ego vero
>   volo in virtute vim esse quam maximam;
>
> Verum hoc idem saepe faciamus. Huic mori optimum esse propter
>   desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem vivere. Si enim ita est,
>   vide ne facinus facias, cum mori suadeas. Indicant pueri, in quibus ut
>   in speculis natura cernitur. Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae
>   actiones. An est aliquid per se ipsum flagitiosum, etiamsi nulla
>   comitetur infamia? Non autem hoc: igitur ne illud quidem. Res enim se
>   praeclare habebat, et quidem in utraque parte.

---

Your task, given the input `t` from above, is to apply one formatting operations at random once per paragraph, defined by the following list of operations:

- **Character Run Operations** (Should be performed on 1-5 word runs chosen at random. This should NEVER cross sentence boundaries (\n|.|?|!))

  - Bold `<b></b>`
  - Italic `<i></i>`
  - Underline `<u></u>`
- **Sentence Operations** (Should be performed on 1-2 sentences in the paragraph)

  - Block Quote `<blockquote></blockquote>`
  - Preface `<pre></pre>`
  - Heading `<h1></h1> ... <h6></h6>` (Chosen at random)
- **Paragraph Operations** (Should turn entire paragraph into this format, separated by sentences if the operation is segmented (like a list)).

  - Unordered List `<ul><li>Sentence 1</li>...<li>Sentence n</li></ul>`
  - Ordered List `<ol><li>Sentence 1</li>...<li>Sentence n</li></ol>`

So, here is one possible random output:

```
[1:HEADING(h1 chosen),2:BOLD(4 times),3:PREFACE(1 sentence),4:UNORDERED-LIST,5:BLOCKQUOTE(2 sentences)]
```

Applied to the input from above (`t`):

> ## Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> Quonam, inquit, modo? Progredientibus autem aetatibus sensim tardeve
>   potius quasi nosmet ipsos cognoscimus. Quod non faceret, si in
>   voluptate summum bonum poneret. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
>
> Tubulo **putas dicere**? Cum salvum esse flentes sui respondissent,
>   rogavit **essentne fusi** hostes. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat.
>   **Satisne ergo pudori consulat, si quis sine** teste libidini
>   pareat? Negare non possum. An hoc usque quaque, aliter in **vita**?
>   Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest.
>   Quid ei reliquisti, nisi te, quoquo modo loqueretur, intellegere, quid
>   diceret?
>
> Itaque ad tempus ad Pisonem omnes. Universa enim illorum ratione cum
>   tota vestra confligendum puto. Haec dicuntur inconstantissime. Dicimus
>   aliquem hilare vivere; Qui non moveatur et offensione turpitudinis et
>   comprobatione honestatis?
>
> ```
> Sed quot homines, tot sententiae;
> Quippe: habes enim a rhetoribus; Omnes enim iucundum motum, quo sensus
> hilaretur.
> ```
>
> Tria genera bonorum; Profectus in exilium Tubulus
>   statim nec respondere ausus;
>
> - Certe non potest.
> - Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo
>     beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; Graece donan, Latine voluptatem
>     vocant.
> - Itaque a sapientia praecipitur se ipsam, si usus sit,
>     sapiens ut relinquat.
> - Quid est igitur, inquit, quod requiras?
>     Atque haec coniunctio confusioque virtutum tamen a philosophis ratione
>     quadam distinguitur.
> - Ego vero volo in virtute vim esse quam
>     maximam;
>
> > Verum hoc idem saepe faciamus. Huic mori optimum esse
> >   propter desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem
> >   vivere.
>
> Si enim ita est, vide ne facinus facias, cum mori
>   suadeas. Indicant pueri, in quibus ut in speculis natura cernitur.
>   Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones. An est aliquid per
>   se ipsum flagitiosum, etiamsi nulla comitetur infamia? Non autem hoc:
>   igitur ne illud quidem. Res enim se praeclare habebat, et quidem in
>   utraque parte.

Wow! Isn't that much prettier? Here's the code view:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1> Quonam, inquit, modo? Progredientibus autem aetatibus sensim tardeve potius quasi nosmet ipsos cognoscimus. Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.

Tubulo <b>putas dicere</b>? Cum salvum esse flentes sui respondissent, rogavit <b>essentne fusi</b> hostes. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat. <b>Satisne ergo pudori consulat, si quis sine</b> teste libidini pareat? Negare non possum. An hoc usque quaque, aliter in <b>vita</b>? Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest. Quid ei reliquisti, nisi te, quoquo modo loqueretur, intellegere, quid diceret?

Itaque ad tempus ad Pisonem omnes. Universa enim illorum ratione cum tota vestra confligendum puto. Haec dicuntur inconstantissime. Dicimus aliquem hilare vivere; Qui non moveatur et offensione turpitudinis et comprobatione honestatis? <pre>Sed quot homines, tot sententiae; Quippe: habes enim a rhetoribus; Omnes enim iucundum motum, quo sensus hilaretur.</pre> Tria genera bonorum; Profectus in exilium Tubulus statim nec respondere ausus;

<ul><li>Certe non potest.</li><li>Dempta enim aeternitate nihilo beatior Iuppiter quam Epicurus; Graece donan, Latine voluptatem vocant.</li><li>Itaque a sapientia praecipitur se ipsam, si usus sit, sapiens ut relinquat.</li><li>Quid est igitur, inquit, quod requiras? Atque haec coniunctio confusioque virtutum tamen a philosophis ratione quadam distinguitur.</li><li>Ego vero volo in virtute vim esse quam maximam;</li></ul>

<blockquote>Verum hoc idem saepe faciamus. Huic mori optimum esse propter desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem vivere.</blockquote>Si enim ita est, vide ne facinus facias, cum mori suadeas. Indicant pueri, in quibus ut in speculis natura cernitur. Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones. An est aliquid per se ipsum flagitiosum, etiamsi nulla comitetur infamia? Non autem hoc: igitur ne illud quidem. Res enim se praeclare habebat, et quidem in utraque parte.
```

Take note specifically of how I split the sentences on the paragraph operators, you delimit by ONLY periods and NEWLINES, nothing else ends a sentence. Also, make not of how the character run operators can span multiple words, BUT NOT MULTIPLE SENTENCES, you must stop before the next sentence begins (EXCLUDING THE ENDING NEWLINE OR PERIOD). As in, it's only applicable to the `<character_run>` language definition.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) lowest byte-count will be declared the winner.

Comment: I think you're missing `;` from `<sentence_end>`. I also don't see any sentences ending in `\n`, but perhaps you were referring to the end of a paragraph? Also, I think the `<paragraph>` rule should be `<sentence> | <sentence><paragraph>`.

Comment: @ETHproductions that sentence doesn't end due to the `;`, rather it ends due to the newline.

Comment: Coulda sworn at least one person would like this haha.

Comment: Are you sure about character runs including *any* ASCII char except newline or period? I would restrict it to `[A-Za-z ]`, at least for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

## Task Scheduling [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given as input:

- A unix time at which to first run the program
- Delay between runs (can be `0`)
- Number of times to run the program (`-1` if infinite)
- A program to be run through the console when triggered

Run the program under specified conditions.

- You can assume your program will always be running
- Run the equivalent of `nohup <command> &`.

Comment: What happens if the unix time is before now?  What is the delay measured in?  What should I do if the delay is 0?  What do you mean by "You can assume your program is always running?"  Isn't the ability to keep my program running up to my program?.  `nohup` is not a command I'm familiar with, so I'd definitely explain that.

Comment: @NathanMerrill 1. undefined behavor, ie do whatever you want 2. seconds 3. undefined behavior 4. if you want to 5. it isn't?

Comment: All of that needs to be in the in the post.

Answer (score 0):

### Binary beads <s>clock</s>

The challenge is dedicated to pseudo-graphical representation of objects, e.g. like by ascii-art.
Puzzle is geometrical: to represent bistrings as beads using tiles.
The result must be beads-like strings where one is more like a bead and zero is more like a stem (or smaller bead).
The solution can result in wide variety of visual concept but there are specific guides, see below.

A simple example of binary beads using single tiles, here standard characters:
Input: 1001, 0101, 0011.
Output:

```
s--s
-s-s
--ss
```

or e.g. [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII) console:

[image]

So these are only example form, but now you must "upscale" it, but since
you are not in graphical mode, the resulting image must be structure of source units, i.e. it must be a rectangular tiling.
In other words. it is not allowed just to draw sprites for each next upscale step. So the whole must be
a real console app or code which emulates the console behaviour itself within the guidelines.
So you can draw any tiles and use them also. Solution should show some reference to console output,
e.g. if using graphical lib, a "print" function should be made which takes the data.

### Task

The task is to write an application or function wich draws scalable yet visually consistent beads with efective
usage of tiles. Tilesets with least amount of tiles and yet with outstanding rich beads look must win. In other words, one should find good relation between tiles amount and good possibility to present different sizes.

One can present different length strings, but the whole layout must be of adequate size. Multiple words on line is allowed and even welcome especially if shows interesting use case.
Usage of graphical libs is welcome, e.g. to emulate a simple console-like output.
All tiles can be custom, i.e. this should not be necessarily standard characters of console. In real console any characters possible can be used or patched with custom tiles if possible.
Any OS can be used.

### Restrictions:

**Final image**:

- must include at least 2 different types of beads (different sizes), i.e. interesting scalability example
- each bead type *must share* some tiles with other beads
- structures should be good visible from various distance and contiguos as possible
- "zero=stem, ones=bead" rule is *not* strict, creativity is very welcome but it should be not too far from rule to compare results
- artiscism in forms is always bonus points!

**Tiles**:

- maximal amount of tiles in the tileset : **16**
- are **rectangular**, e.g 16x8, 8x8 pixels ...
- minimal size: 6x6, maximal size: 24x24 pixels
- only two-color but the whole image can have more colors.

**Code**:

- Non-cryptic plain code: C, Python, Basic, Fortran and those not too far from it
- hacks (e.g. for old platforms) should be documented somehow and reproducable in theory

## Points given for:

- less unique tiles yet with rich possibilities
- visual consistence by each beads type presented, but two types must *not* necesserily have same style
- Hint: even within one type, the look of one bead can vary but the whole string easily decodable
- interesting scaling possibilities, e.g. parametric scaling
- fullfill the restrictions
- less operations and minimalistic code
- working application, e.g. interactive counter or a micro-game is welcome

**Solution publishing:**

- title: amount of tiles used and pixel sizes info
- visual examples easy to follow
- notes about interesting sides of solution
- code and some explanation

**Sandbox note:**
If there are unclear point, free to point to corrections.
Please suppose better tags if needed.

Tags: [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[typography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography)[binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

Comment: I really like this challenge, though I'd remove the "only monochrome mode is allowed" rule to give the designers more freedom. I'd also include only the first primitive output example, and add a line stating that users are free to format this, since all these examples might push all answers roughly in the same direction. Maybe you can make an answer as well, since the PETSCII example looks great!

Comment: I fear that this question is too broad for a popularity-contest.  There are two primary problems:  1. The judgement criterion (which clock is most useful to low-sighted people) does *not* naturally gather votes.  You are *far* more likely to get upvoted answers that are funny and interesting.  2. The challenge isn't really about programming, but about design.

Comment: If you are wanting design help, ux.stackexchange is *great* for that.  If you want people to implement a specific clock, then make objective requirements, and change the challenge type :)

Comment: Hi @NathanMerrill, thanks for input. The aim is not for people with low vision, it is just background, I will make that point more clear. And do you mean design challenge is not welcome here? My idea was exactly to challenge different designs with few restrictions.

Comment: Right.  Design questions aren't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

### The many names of Túrin

Tolkien's character Túrin had a multiple personality disorder and consequently needed to change name on a regular basis to be called by something fitting its current mood. He has been known as *Turambar*, *Mormegil*, *Gorthol*, *Adanedhel*, *Dagnir Glaurunga*, *the Wildman of the Woods*, *Neithan* and some other unofficial nicknames alluding to his tenderness for his sister.

This must have been a real headache for the author: not only had he to find the new names but he also had to remember the translation in English<sup>1</sup>, since every new name is introduced along the lines of "From this day he was known as [*Compound_Elvish_word*], that is [*Word of word*]"

Your task is to automatize the production of epithets to help Tolkien finish his Unfinished Tales.

Given a list of Sindarin<sup>2</sup> substantives and their English translations (see list below) as an external file, a list or any reasonable format, **randomly** take two Sindarin substantives (repetition is possible) and print
*"From this day he was known as **Sindarin1sindarin2**, that is **English2** of **English1**"*

(Note the **inversion** of words in the translation, and the **capitalisation**)

**Input**: none

**Output**: A string

**The list:**
(names can be capitalized in your own list, but the formatting must be consistent. The order of the couples can also be changed)

```
Sindarin    English
--------------------
amarth      fate
ang         iron
aur         morning
brethil     birch
carch       fang
celeb       silver
draug       wolf
galad       glittering
glor        light
gwathel     sister
manadh      doom
megil       sword
melethron   lover
mor         darkness
naur        flame
taur        forest
```

**Examples:**

- From this day he was known as Galadaur, that is Morning of
  Glittering
- From this day he was known as Mormelethron, that is Lover
  of Darkness
- From this day he was known as Draugdraug, that is Wolf of
  Wolf

Hobbits played golf and Codë was the Vala of challenges in the Silmarillion, so this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

<sup>1</sup> Sorry, Tolkien specialists, I'm probably massacring Quenya, Sindarin and many other concepts

<sup>2</sup> I think

Comment: Children *do* visit this website, so if you consider something unsuitable for them, do not mention it at all, even to hint at avoiding mentioning it.

Comment: Changed as asked, the example as well.

Comment: 1. *Substantives* are far more commonly called *nouns* in English. 2. This would be a more interesting challenge if the word list had a lot of common substrings to exploit for compression. Maybe it would work better with a fictional language rather than Sindarin?

Answer (score 0):

## Minimum exchange of bills

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

You're at the supermarket, buying groceries for the week.  At the end, the cashier rings up your cart and declares that your total cost is exactly `$76`.  You reach into your wallet, and find a `$50`, four `$20s`, and a `$1`, for a total of six bills.

We consider a `transaction` to be you paying money to the cashier, and the cashier giving you your change (if applicable).  Your `total` for a transaction is the net amount of money you owe the cashier, which is calculated by the `amount you pay` less `the amount of change you get`.  We can think of a transaction as adding the bills you pay to the cashier, and subtracting the bills you get in return.  Thus, the following is a non-exhaustive list of possible transactions in this scenario:

```
$50 + $20 + $20 - $10 - $1 - $1 - $1 - $1 (8 bills)
$20 + $20 + $20 + $20 - $1 - $1 - $1 - $1 (8 bills)
$20 + $20 + $20 + $20 + $1 - $5           (6 bills)
$50 + $20 + $20 + $1 - $10 - $5           (6 bills)
```

Given a total of $76, and having 1 $50, 4 $20s, and 1 $1, the minimum exchange of bills comes out to 6 bills.

### Challenge

Given an integer `Bill` and a list of bills in your wallet `[Ones Fives Tens Twenties Fifties Hundreds]`, calculate the number of bills in a minimum exchange of bills between you and the cashier.

### Rules

1. Your program can accept your input in any reasonable way.  You can accept an integer followed by a list of six integers separated by reasonable means. You can accept seven integers separated by any reasonable means. If your language cannot accept input in any reasonable form, you may, at no penalty, hardcode the input into your program.  **You may only hardcode input if your language cannot reasonably accept meaningful input**.
2. Your program must output the **number of bills in the minimum exchange transaction**.  Your program may not print any of the possible transactions themselves.
3. You may assume that you will always have enough money to cover your bill, possibly requiring some change from the cashier.
4. You may assume that the cashier has an unlimited number of all bills at their disposal.
5. You may assume that all inputs are non-negative integers.  It is possible that your bill comes out to $0.  No integer input will ever be greater than `1000`.  That's too many bills and quite frankly, too many groceries.
6. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Input                        Output
[76,1,0,0,4,1,0]              6
```

I'll come up with and post some more test cases if people think this is a good challenge.

### Possible bonus challenge:

In the United States, a $2 is a rare, but legal, bill issued by the treasury.  If you wish, you can have your program accept another integer, between the number of Ones and Fives, representing the number of $2-bills you have in your wallet, which you can use to pay for your groceries.  However, since such bills are so uncommon, the cashier will not have any on-hand to give to you as change.

Comment: Never allow arbitrary separators in the input, at least without some length limit; some languages may be able to slip the entire program in there. The easiest method is normally to say that the program takes a list of integers as input via any reasonable means; we have various rulings on Meta about which means are reasonable, and that saves you having to duplicate it in your challenge. I'd recommend against the bonus challenge, by the way; it just makes entries harder to compare.

Comment: Essentially the making change problem ( http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70847/194 and probably others) but adding negative value coins (bills). There's a risk it will be closed as dupe; it's borderline enough that I wouldn't cast a supervote. One thing I will suggest, as I have in the past on this type of question, is making the coin (bill) system be input rather than hard-coded. That way you can forget about the bonus challenge and the question feels a bit less culture-specific.

Comment: I vote no on $2 bills, that sounds like it doesn't add much.

Answer (score 0):

### Find square sum products [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

It's possible to find sets of three numbers whose product including their sum is a square number. Examples:

- (3 + 2 + 1) * 3 * 2 * 1 = 6²
- (3 + 3 + 2) * 3 * 3 * 2 = 12²
- (4 + 4 + 1) * 4 * 4 * 1 = 12²
- (9 + 8 + 1) * 9 * 8 * 1 = 36²
- (8 + 5 + 5) * 8 * 5 * 5 = 60²
- (8 + 7 + 6) * 8 * 7 * 6 = 84²
- (9 + 8 + 8) * 9 * 8 * 8 = 120²

Please write a program or function to find square sum products for me.

Since there are an infinite number of square sum products, even excluding trivial multiples, you should limit your output to depend on a characteristic number N. Your program should always output the same square sum product(s) for a given N, and there should be at least one value of N for each possible square sum product that will cause your program to output that product. However, I will be flexible in what N actually represents, as long as you describe it in your answer. Here are some examples:

- N is one sixth<sup>[citation needed]</sup> of the square root of the square sum products. For example, an N of 2 would find the second and third of my examples.
- N is the upper bound of the largest summand. For example, an N of 9 would find all of my examples and then some.
- N is the number of square sum products to be found. For example, an N of 12 would find all of my examples and then some.

For the output, I don't actually want the summands or the square root. Instead, please output the pairwise sum of the summands. Please also exclude duplicates (i.e. reorderings) from your answer.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins!

Comment: You can drop the first [citation needed]: if `(a, b, c)` is a valid triple, then so is `(a*k, b*k, c*k)` for `k` integral.

Comment: @Sp3000 Sure, but that's a trivial case. I'm pretty sure there are infinite nontrivial cases too.

Comment: My point was just that an infinite number do exist, so you can drop the superscript. I'm sure you could come up with something less trivial if you really wanted, like `(2*k*k+4*k+2, 2*k*k+4*k+3, 1)`

Comment: @Sp3000 Indeed, you can generate a subset by multiplying a triangular number by 4, and taking that number twice with a final 1.

Comment: I find the proposed relationship between input and output too vague, and also open to abuse. For example, I could say that every single N outputs 6^2 unless N is of the form 2^a 3^b 5^c where a,b,c generate a square sum product. Why not just pick a spec, for example, that N is the upper bound of the largest summand?

Comment: @GregMartin I didn't want to be overly restrictive because on other sandbox posts I atttracted comments complaining about what I chose to spec, but I guess some sort of restriction is necessary, sigh...

Comment: I agree that it's not always clear what will make the best challenge...!

Answer (score 0):

## Dual Kimian (Error) and Regular Quine Polyglot [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Create a program that is

- a non-erroring [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) in one language...
- ...and a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) that produces its own source code through an error in another language

#### What is an error quine?

> The compiler/interpreter/runtime to produce *error output* when compiling/running your program which is identical to your program's source code.
>
> - Your program may be specific to a particular version or implementation of your language's compiler/interpreter/runtime environment. If so, please specify the particulars.
> - Only standard compiler/interpreter/runtime options are permitted. You cannot pass some weird flag to your compiler to get a specific result.
> - The program does *not* need to be syntactically or semantically valid.
> - The program must not produce any output of its own (e.g. by calling `print` or an output function). All output generated upon attempting to compile/run the program must originate from the compiler/interpreter/runtime.
> - The complete output of the compiler/interpreter/runtime must be exactly identical to your program source code.
> - The compiler/interpreter/runtime must generate at least one error message when invoked with your program.
>
> <sup>(adapted from [nneonneo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6699/nneonneo) ["Make an error quine!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/make-an-error-quine) challenge)</sup>

- Polyglots from different versions of the same language or similar languages are allowed

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11151/62131)

Comment: I fear the spec here isn't clear enough to prevent people using absurd definitions of what counts as an error, like happened in my attempt. (For example, what happens if you throw a string, and the runtime's unhandled-exception handler prints it? Some people consider that to be an error, and it's printed by the runtime, but the text is entirely under user control.)

Answer (score 0):

## Sandbox Questions

- Is it a good idea to post this as a separate challenge? This one is significantly easier and I fear that posting it would take too much attention away from the original challenge.

---

## Detect if your program has been bit-flipped [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening)

Write a program that outputs

```
NOT CORRUPTED
```

If any single **bit** is substituted by **the alternate bit** the program should output

```
CORRUPTED
```

- Do not read your source code from a file

Comment: Isn't this already a question? If so why not just replace it with a link to the question?

Answer (score 0):

## Avoiding Averages

Given a non-empty list of positive integers, reorder the list such that for every pair of indices, the average of the values at those indices is not contained in any index between them.

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.

**Work in-progress**

Comment: Maybe add some sample input->output?

Comment: I like this, but there's also not much here. Maybe add a picture of a kitten or some I/O like Leo said.

Comment: Can we expect the input to be valid, or if not, what should be done if such an ordering does not exist? (e.g. `[1,1,1]`).

Comment: @flawr I'm wondering the same thing, should the input always have a possible solution. If multiple solutions exist, return only one or all of them? I'm still ironing out the details.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a set of numbers that doesn't have a possible ordering (where each number occurs once).  I think returning only 1 is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the CYK-Table!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grammars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars)

---

### Context-Free Grammars

A [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) is a grammar consisting of rules from one variable to a list of variables and symbols. Every string purely consisting of symbols that can be produced using these rules is said to be accepted by the language. For the purpose of this challenge we're only going to consider grammars in [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) which means that on the right side there's either two variables or one symbol (we're gonna ignore the empty language for this challenge).

### The CYK-Algorithm

[The CYK-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm#Example) is a method to check whether a given word is recognized by a context-free language in CNF. For doing this it iterates over the word and applies all possible rules on all substrings and writes them down in a nice table. This table can then be used to successively find variables generating larger substrings until you (don't) hit the word.

### The Input

Your input will be

- A list of strings representing the word
- A list of triples of strings, representing the rules from one variables (the first in the triple) to two variables
- A list of pairs of strings, representing the rules from one variable to a symbol
- A string, representing the starting variable

You may replace the above input format with your favorite input format, as long as you can encode the same amount of information.

### The output

The output will be three-dimensional: A list of rows consisting of a list of "candidates" which is a list of strings representing a list of variables. An illustration of this is [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm#Example).

You may replace the above output format with your favorite output format, as long as you can encode the same amount of information.

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes to solve the challenge wins!

### Example

```
Start Symbol: "X"
Word: ["b","a","c","b"]
Rules #1: [("X","X","Y"),("X","Z","Z"),("Y","W","Z"),("Z","X","Y"),("W","Y","W")]
Rules #2: [("X","a"),("Y","a"),("Z","b"),("W","c")]
```

We're gonna do this step-by-step:

The substrings of length 1 first (this is your first row):

```
b    , a       , c   , b
["Z"],["X","Y"],["W"],["Z"]
```

Now for the substrings of length 2 (this is your second row):

```
[],["W"],["Y"]
```

(because there's no way to get `ZX` or `ZY`, but `W -> YW` and `Y -> WZ`)

Now for the substrings of length 3 (this is your third row):

```
[],["X","Y","Z"]
```

(because there's no rule to get `ZW`, but `X->XY (1+2), Y->WZ (2+1), Z->XY (1+2)` where the sum denotes the lengths of of the used substrings)

Finally for the substrings of length 4 (this is your fourth row):

```
["X"]
```

(because `X->ZZ(1+3)`)

So in total your final table for this example is gonna look like this:

```
[
[["Z"],["X","Y"],["W"],["Z"]],
[[],["W"],["Y"]],
[[],["X","Y","Z"]],
[["X"]]
]
```

where the first index increases as we go downwards, the second increases as we go to the right an dthe third denotes the variable within the "cell".

Answer (score 0):

## Physical String Length

**Given the following information:**

- `(String) s` -  A string to be printed.
- `(String) f` -  The font in which it is to be printed.
- `(int)   pt` - The size of the font in which it is to be printed in pts (no decimals).

  - Note that the input units are in pt (1/72 inch).
  - The output unit should be pixels, rounded to the nearest integer.
  - Use 96 PPI in your conversion.

**Output:**

- The physical length of the string (how many pixels wide the final string is).

Below are a few examples and a piece of code that will let you test arbitrary combinations.

---

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Font;
public class F {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Calibri", 12));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Calibri", 24));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Calibri", 36));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Calibri", 72));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Helvetica", 12));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Times New Roman", 12));
        System.out.println(physicalStringLength("What?", "Courier New", 12));
    }
    
    public static int physicalStringLength(String s, String f, int pt) {
        System.out.print(s + "@[" + f + "," + pt + "]=");
        return new Canvas().getFontMetrics(new Font(f,0,pt)).stringWidth(s);
    }
}
```

Here's some base-line examples, the output has be created using the above piece of Java code:

```
What?@[Calibri,12]=35
What?@[Calibri,24]=65
What?@[Calibri,36]=97
What?@[Calibri,72]=193
What?@[Helvetica,12]=35
What?@[Times New Roman,12]=31
What?@[Courier New,12]=35
```

If you want to see the length of any other strings, use the code provided as a base-line. Using a Java has been banned due to the usage of the example unless you'll be providing a different methodology (kinda sucks, cause Java may be one of the few with a built-in).

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: The font is an integer?

Comment: Yep, no float font sizes.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the second parameter "f"

Comment: Nope, that's a typo.

Comment: It's a little strange to ask for the width in px but input the font size in pt. Pixels are can vary in physical size while points are fixed at 1/72 inches.

Comment: @Poke I guess I could state that Java is using a default PPI is 96.

Comment: Because I like answering challenges in java I'd be remiss if I didn't suggest adding more to this challenge such as height and other things found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) but that's likely not as fun for other languages. I think the challenge **does** contain enough by itself.

Comment: 1. I don't think this is well defined. Different applications using the same typeface and the same point size will produce strings of slightly different widths because e.g. they don't interpret the hints in the same way. 2. Why ban Java and not e.g. the .Net languages, which have very similar library support?

Comment: Adding to Peter's point, different rendering engines display fonts differently. The default Windows GDI renderer alone knows 5 different types of anti-aliasing, any of which can be the system standard, not counting fonts rendered by Direct2D, OpenGL or GDI+. It's very easy to just render and measure a string with GDI+, but the length might be different across systems by one or two pixels because of AA. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe adding in a clause about acceptable standard deviations?

Answer (score 0):

## Binary Grids

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

Consider the N-dimensional binary grid, with dimensions {d1,d2,...,dN}. Here are a few examples:

6 (N=1): `100101`

3x7 (N=2):

```
1001001
0110110
1001001
```

3x3x3 (N=3):

```
010   001   100
100   011   110
011   110   001
```

What each of these example grids have in common is: *they do not contain any consecutive sequences of the same digit longer than 2.*

**The Challenge**

Write a program or function which, given a list of dimensions, outputs the number of binary grid configurations with the given dimensions that satisfy this condition.

**Input**

A list of positive integers (>1), either via stdin or passed as an argument. Example: `3 2 6`, `[3,2,6]`, etc.

**Output**

The number of valid configurations, either as a returned value or printed to stdout, or something similar.

**Constraints**

- While brute-force solutions can work, their time complexity is *O(2^N)*, which is way too long for anything but the smallest grids. Write something which will complete before my computer becomes obsolete, please!
- Standard loopholes are forbidden, not that I think very many of them would apply here anyway.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins, with tiebreakers going to the fastest code.

### Sandbox Questions

1. Is this interesting?
2. Is this doable?
3. What's a better way to word the time complexity restrictions?
4. The only example for which I actually know the answer is for `[6]`... do I need more? I'd have to solve this myself first...

Comment: 1. I think "*consecutive*" needs clarification. I'm guessing that it's talking about horizontal and vertical lines but not diagonal ones. 2. Re whether it's doable: in 1D it's http://oeis.org/A128588 which is easy to calculate. In general it can be done in n-D by calculating all of the acceptable values in some (n-1)-D projection and then taking the power of an incidence graph, but I doubt that scales well beyond 3D. It may be possible with some investigation to get an n-D generating function, but it's hard to tell without spending a couple of hours on the problem.

Comment: In terms of complexity restrictions, asking the program to run in polynomial time in the number of cells in the grid seems reasonable (because exponential time is enough to brute-force it and it's very rare (impossible?) for a program to have a complexity in between). I don't know whether that's possible, though (although even if there's a chance that it isn't, it may still be worth asking the question).

Answer (score 0):

## Golf Me a Bubble Sort

Your task is to create a program that performs a bubble sort.
For those who don't know, a bubble sort is a simple sorting algorithm where two adjacent items are taken & swapped if they are in the wrong order until all values are in the correct order.

---

### Rules

1. You must provide an explanation for how your answer does a bubble sort.
2. You may *not* use built-in or standard library sorting algorithms. You must make your own code.
3. Your program should take a group of numbers as input and output them in the correct order.

   - Input format: `10 5 9 2 . . . (and so on)`
   - Output can be an array returned by the program when run.
   - Output can also be the correctly ordered values separated by whitespace.
4. Speed does not matter as much as of the program functions.

---

### Test Cases

- `10 5 9 2 1 6 8 3 7 4` (you can format it differently depending on your language)
- `1 2 5 4 3`

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: It may be a better idea to have entries do only a single iteration of bubble sort; that way it will be easy to verify their correctness.

Answer (score 0):

## Find fixed points of the Logistic Map

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

## Definitions

#### Logistic Map

A logistic map is defined as the following equation:

[image: equation]

Where the next value in the map (on the left) is determined by a function of the current value (on the right), where the constant lambda represents a set constant between zero and four (non-inclusive, along the reals).

#### Stable Point

A "stable point" in relation to a map is a point which is approached repeatedly by iterating the logistic map. They are distinct, and there are one to many for any given lambda.

## The Task

Write a function or program which, given an input real value `n` between zero and four (non-inclusive), returns the number of stable points for a map where lambda is `n`.

## Examples

**Soon to be added**

---

## Meta

Main problem: Defining "stable point". Is this definition sufficient?

Comment: The definition is wrong. A fixed point of a map is a point which is mapped to itself. For the logistic map the fixed points are `0` and `1-1/x`.

Comment: If you instead look for points in stable cycles, you need to also specify that the domain is the real numbers, because stable cycles correspond to roots in the polynomial obtained by iterating the map, and over the complex numbers a polynomial always has as many roots as its order. If you specify *distinct* points in stable cycles of any length, that becomes a real challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The second one was what I was going for. :P Got my terminology wrong.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Just to verify, I'm looking for the number of distinct stable points for specific values of lambda along [this graph](https://www.geogebra.org/m/wQbHRgye).

Answer (score 0):

**Language contest**

*Moving this here from normal question*

So, I'm kind of an esolang loony so let me propose the following contest.
First of all, we do not care about speed: if two algorithms safe the same problems then they are 'equally good' at least for this challenge. Also, let's think in "special case" terms.
Sorting is the problem of well... sorting a list. However, an algorithm that generates permutations of lists with an abort condition equally solves the sorting problem. However, such an algorithm is more generic as the abort condition allows it to do more stuff. In other words: sorting a list is just a special case of generating permutations with an abort condition.

The idea is to concentrate on the most generic version of an algorithm that solves a problem. In other terms: Getting rid of redundant built-ins in esoteric programming languages.

The contest would go as following:
The goal is to create an esoteric concatenative language (not necessarily stack based but concatenative) with the fewest built-ins that solve all problems (in some catalog). However, this would be really boring like that because a minimized version of brainfuck would pretty much win. Thus the 'score' function would likely be a function of 'amount of built-ins' and 'average program length'. One other constraint is that you are not allowed to have redundancy in your built-ins. If you have a built-in `sortAsc` and `sortDesc` and `reverse` then `sortAsc = reverse . sortDesc` thus you are disqualified. This also means that if you have too generic loops as built-ins like uhm `for` loops you can use these `for` loops to create a sort function which means you wouldn't be allowed to have a `sort` function.

What do you guys think?

TL;DR optimize for program length and least amount of builtins required.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but the rule against redundancy is problematic. It's very difficult (in fact undecidable) to say whether the built-ins of a language are redundant. It's also probable that such limitations can be circumvented with some trick, like having each function take and return a tuple `(d, l)`, where `d` is some arbitrary data and `l` is a string that records which functions were used on the data. You might also want to define unambiguously what a "concatenative language" is.

Comment: I agree with all of Zgarb's comments.  That said, if you enforce a language paradigm, then you could define exactly what "combining commands" means.  If you do do that, then I'd highly recommend making this a code-golf challenge, and dropping "least builtins" as a scoring mechanism

Comment: If you can formulate any built-in in terms of other built-ins then you have redundancy. Hidden state doesn't really count. But yes, there are likely loopholes nobody has thought about yet.

Comment: @mroman Yeah, that's the definition of redundancy. But given an arbitrary list of built-ins, how can you definitively say "this list is not redundant"? Particularly with the weird stuff esolangs tend to have.

Comment: with *handwaving* probably.

Comment: Hmm, I've thought about this some more, and this is what I'd probably do. Drop the non-redundancy requirement, have a lot of smallish tasks (like 20 or so), and have the scoring function be something like **N * 3^B**, where **N** is the total length of the solutions to the tasks and **B** the number of built-ins. Then implementing a redundant built-in would only be worth it if it cut off 2/3 of your program size across all tasks. I'll have to think about it more to see if there are obvious loopholes that I've missed.

Comment: And don't get me wrong, I think this is a superb challenge idea! :) It just needs to be done right to have a positive reception and good answers.

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, "*First of all, the assumption is that every algorithm that solves the same problem is equally fast*" is nonsense, and primes readers with a background in computer science to expect the whole question to be low quality. I suggest rephrasing as "*First of all, the assumption is that we don't care about performance*".

Comment: Okay, I think I have found another "loophole". Suppose you have **K** tasks. Then you can make 3 built-ins and solve each task with a program of length **1 + ceiling(log2(K))** as follows. One built-in does "encoding": it transforms the data into some more restricted format (like multiply every list element by 2 to make them even, if the data is always a list of integers). The other two built-ins work as follows. (contd.)

Comment: If the encoded data has been processed by fewer than **ceiling(log2(K))-1** functions, they just add a unique marker to the encoding (like by appending `1` or `3` depending on the function). Otherwise, the applied built-ins (counting the current one) form a binary string of length **ceiling(log2(K))**, which we interpret as a base-2 number encoding the task. Then we just decode the data and solve that task.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It just means that for this challenge it doesn't *really* matter how fast your program is as long as it solves the task in a (meaningful) finite amount of time.

Comment: @Zgarb I can't really follow that. Do you have a more practical/real example of that loophole?

Comment: If that's what it's *intended* to mean, write that instead, because as it stands it's very easy to interpret it as meaning something different.

Comment: @mroman [Here's an implementation in Python 3.](http://ideone.com/xaj1lM) I hope you can follow it. I'm using 8 tasks as an example, which results in length-4 programs. Each program has the form `Eabc`, where `abc` is the binary encoding of the task number.

Comment: @zgarb yeah I get it now. I guess that's legal to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Detect skewed exponential sequences

[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Observe the following sequence:

```
1 3 9 54 162 729 2187 6561 19683
```

We can see that this is equivalent to:

```
1 *    1
1 *    3
1 *    9
2 *   27
2 *   81
3 *  243
3 *  729
3 * 2187
3 * 6561
```

The sequence on the right is the first 9 values of the exponential function `f(x) = 3^x`, that is, the exponential function of 3. It is multiplied element-wise by `1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3`. Now, this sequences is strictly non-decreasing.

Your challenge is to, given a sequence **K** of length **c**, determine if there is a strictly non-decreasing list of integers **L** such that each element **e**<sub>**j**</sub> of (**K** / **L**) (element-wise division) is equal to **b**<sup>**j**</sup>, for 0 ≤ **j** < **c**, and for some **b** > 1.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

### True cases

```
1                    (1 * 1, base = any)
1 3 9                (1 1 1 * 1 3 9, base = 3)
2 4 8 32             (2 2 2 4 * 1 2 4 8, base = 2)
1 9 27               (1 3 3 * 1 3 9, base = 3)
1 5 500 2500 13125   (1 1 20 20 21 * 1 5 25 125 625, base = 5)
```

### False cases

```
1 1 1 1              (false because this would have base = 0)
1 2 3 4              (no base)
1 2 4 32 16          (decreasing multiplier)
```

Comment: According to how you have it stated right now, the lists 1 1 1 1 and 1 2 3 4 can be done. It should be b>1 if you want it to not be possible.

Comment: @LliwTelracs Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve for X

**Given an equation using the following symbols:**

- Parenthesis: `()`
- Operators: `+-/*`
- Variable: `x`
- Comparators: `<=>`

**And the following guarantees:**

- There will only ever be one `x` variable.
- `x` / `0` will never be in the denominator.
- Only one comparator will be used (no `>=` or `<=`).
- All numbers used in the input will be integers.
- Numbers in the output may be expressed as decimals, the chosen precision should be `>= 3`.

**Output the correct reduction for the value of `x`.**

- Output should be in the form: `x[Operator][Decimal]` (E.G. `x=2`)

  - `2=x` is not acceptable, you must have x on the left side.

---

Here are a few examples (The last part in bold is the part you need to output):

`2+2=x`
`4=x`
**`x=4`**

`x=4*3+(2-2)`
`x=4*3+0`
**`x=12`**

`1+(x/4)-2=0`
`1+(x/4)=2`
`(x/4)=1`
**`x=4`**

`-2*(2+x)>-1*12`
`-2*(2+x)>-12`
`(2+x)<6`
**`x<4`**

`-2*x<(29+1)/6`
`-2*x<(30)/6`
`-2*x+2<5`
`-2*x<3`
**`x>-6`**

`(x/-1)*(10/-4)=10*5`
`(x/-1)*(10/-4)=50`
`(x/-1)=-20`
**`x=20`**

`(x/-5)*-1+2*8>0`
`(x/-5)*-1+16>0`
`(x/-5)*-1>-16`
`(x/-5)<16`
**`x>-80`**

`-1*(4*(6*(x/7)))<10`
`(4*(6*(x/7)))>-10`
`(6*(x/7))>-2.5`
`(x/7)>-0.416`
**`x>-2.916`**

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count will be deemed the winner.

Comment: I'm not convinced this can be solved faster than brute force in the general case (although a golfed solution would likely use brute force anyway). On another subject, what should be the answer for input like `x>4` `x<6`?

Comment: Return it, as is.

Answer (score 0):

## Same Same But Different [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

This challenge involves two similar digit-based routines each of which, when given a non-negative integer seed, produce eventually periodic sequences.
The goal is to find the nth seed number (counting up) that does not define the two sequences to be the identical (by virtue of the order of its digits), yet does yield sequences of equal pre-periodic length.

---

#### Reverse & Absolute Difference Routine.

A reverse and difference sequence may be defined in any given base for a non-negative seed by iteratively taking the absolute difference between the number and itself with its digits reversed.

An example:

> The number **544<sub>10</sub>** is **1000100000<sub>2</sub>**;
> The reverse of which is **0000010001<sub>2</sub>**, which is **17<sub>10</sub>**;
> The difference between the two is **527<sub>10</sub>**;
> Repeating the process we have **527<sub>10</sub>** = **1000001111<sub>2</sub>**, reversed is **1111000001<sub>2</sub>** = **961<sub>10</sub>**, and a difference of **434<sub>10</sub>**;
> Repeating again, **434<sub>10</sub>** = **110110010<sub>2</sub>**, reversed is **010011011<sub>2</sub>** = **155<sub>10</sub>**, and a difference of **279<sub>10</sub>**;
> Repeating again yields **186<sub>10</sub>**, then **93<sub>10</sub>**, and then **0**, which will continue to yield **0**.

- So, the pre-periodic reversal and difference base-2 trajectory length of **544<sub>10</sub>** is **six**.
  - since the iterative procedure may be performed **six** times before a periodic part, **{0}**, is reached:

> **544<sub>10</sub>**, **527<sub>10</sub>**, **434<sub>10</sub>**, **279<sub>10</sub>**, **186<sub>10</sub>**, **93<sub>10</sub>**, **{0}**

- Similarly the pre-periodic reversal and difference base-2 trajectory length of **93<sub>10</sub>** is **one**
  ...and the pre-periodic reversal and difference base-2 trajectory length of **0** is **zero** (as it is in any base).

*Note:* Ignoring the *absolute* part of this definition, many low bases have their iterations listed at the OEIS: [base-2](http://oeis.org/A055945), [base-3](http://oeis.org/A055947), [base-4](http://oeis.org/A055949), [base-5](http://oeis.org/A055951), [base-6](http://oeis.org/A055953), [base-7](http://oeis.org/A055955), [base-8](http://oeis.org/A055957), [base-9](http://oeis.org/A055959), [base-10](http://oeis.org/A056965), [base-11](http://oeis.org/A055961), [base-12](http://oeis.org/A055963), [base-16](http://oeis.org/A055965), [base-20](http://oeis.org/A055967).

---

#### Kaprekar Routine.

A similar, but different sequence is the [Kaprekar sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaprekarRoutine.html) where the *absolute difference* above is replaced by the *difference*, and the *reversal* is preceded by a *digit-sort*.

An example:

> The number **836381<sub>10</sub>** is **CC31D<sub>16</sub>**;
> Which, reverse-sorted is **DCC31<sub>16</sub>**, which is **904241<sub>10</sub>**;
> And forward-sorted is **13CCD<sub>16</sub>**, which is **81101<sub>10</sub>**;
> The reverse-sorted less the forward-sorted is then **823140<sub>10</sub>**;
> Repeating the process we have **823140<sub>10</sub>** = **C8F64<sub>16</sub>**, reverse-sorted is **FC864<sub>16</sub>** = **1034340<sub>10</sub>**, forward sorted is **468CF<sub>16</sub>** = **288975<sub>10</sub>**, and the subtraction yields **745365<sub>10</sub>**;
> Repeating again yields **679830<sub>10</sub>**, then **671670<sub>10</sub>**, then **806820<sub>10</sub>**, then **753525<sub>10</sub>**, then **671670<sub>10</sub>**...

- Notice that we have hit a periodic part of the sequence, **{671670<sub>10</sub>, 806820<sub>10</sub>, 753525<sub>10</sub>}**, so the pre-periodic Kaprekar base-16 trajectory of **836381<sub>10</sub>** is **four**:

> **836381<sub>10</sub>**, **823140<sub>10</sub>**, **745365<sub>10</sub>**, **679830<sub>10</sub>**, **{671670<sub>10</sub>, 806820<sub>10</sub>, 753525<sub>10</sub>}**

*Note:*: Once again the OEIS lists the iterations for some low bases: [base-2](http://oeis.org/A164884), [base-3](http://oeis.org/A164993), [base-4](http://oeis.org/A165012), [base-5](http://oeis.org/A165032), [base-6](http://oeis.org/A165051), [base-7](http://oeis.org/A165071), [base-8](http://oeis.org/A165090), [base-9](http://oeis.org/A165110), [base-10](http://oeis.org/A151949).
Furthermore some pre-periodic sequences also exist: [base-2](http://oeis.org/A164885), [base-3](http://oeis.org/A164995), [base-4](http://oeis.org/A165014), [base-5](http://oeis.org/A165034), [base-6](http://oeis.org/A165053), [base-7](http://oeis.org/A165073), [base-8](http://oeis.org/A165092), [base-9](http://oeis.org/A165112), [base-10](http://oeis.org/A151962).

---

#### Same same...

Any number whose digits are already either forward or reverse sorted in some base will have the same pre-periodic trajectory length for both sequences in that base, since the resulting procedure will be identical.

There are, however, numbers which have the same pre-periodic trajectory length in both sequences even though their digits in the base in question are not already sorted.

The first example in base-10 is **107** which has a pre-periodic trajectory length of **three** in both sequences:

Reverse & difference: `107, 594, 99, {0}`
Kaprekar: `107, 693, 594, {495}`

*Aside*: Any number with less than three digits will always be sorted or reverse-sorted, as will the first three digit number, so the only others to actually check in base-10 before finding **107** would be **[102-106]**.

---

#### The challenge

Write a program or function which when provided with a positive* integer, **n**, and an integer base greater than one**, **b**, outputs the **n<sup>th</sup>** number (in the natural ordering) which has neither sorted nor reverse-sorted digits in the given base, **b**, but which *does* have the same pre-periodic trajectory length for both procedures defined above in the given base.

The input and output are as flexible as ever, however the input and output numbers (or string or list representations thereof) are to be in a single unchanging base, consistent between input and output - for most this will probably mean base ten, but any single base is acceptable, as long as it is consistent across any invocations of the code.

* Feel free to have the counting (i.e. **n**) be 0-based if you would prefer, just say in your submission.

** Note there are no such numbers in base-1, so the code does not need to handle b=1 as an input.

---

#### Test cases (one-based n, IO in base-10)

```
 n     b  result
 1     2      17
 2     2      33
 3     2      51
 4     2      65
 5     2      73
 6     2      85
17     2     297

 1     3      28
 2     3      29
 3     3      32
 4     3      48
 5     3      51
 6     3      55
17     3     101

 1    10     107
 2    10     160
 3    10     161
 4    10     172
 5    10     186
 6    10     187
17    10     329

 1    16     264
 2    16     266
 3    16     355
 4    16     373
 5    16     400
 6    16     401
17    16     522

 1   257   66179
 2   257   98949
 3   257   98951
 4   257   98953
 5   257   98955
 6   257   98957
17   257   98979

 1  1234 1523375
 2  1234 2242181
 3  1234 2243417
 4  1234 2244655
 5  1234 2245897
 6  1234 2247147
17  1234 2260770
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A kinda different large number contest

I really like large number's and code puzzles so I really like these large number contests. And I would like to have an other even if it's a duplicate. I feel like a lot of people feel the same way.

So I had to be creative and come up with a slight variation. I had the idea of prohibiting recursion since most of the fast growing techniques require it.
Practically I might a accomplish this by only allowing a single array/list for memory.

I think it's almost impossible to avoid this idea being closed as a duplicate of [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable) but if there is interest I will work it out a lot more. And maybe I will be able to convince 5 people it's an interesting competition despite of the duplicate.

(And in case this is unclear it would be a you have X bytes to make a program the outputs the largest number)

[busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver) [contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest)

Do you have any further ideas, suggestions or tags? Or are you even interested?

Comment: So print the biggest number you can in O(1) complexity?

Comment: 1. Neither the accepted answer nor the top 4 (arguably 5) voted answers in Largest Number Printable use recursion. 2. Bounding the memory is probably quite hard to specify well, but if you do manage it then essentially all you will achieve is to force all the answers to work by counting so as to go through every possible distinct state.

Comment: It's always possible to translate a recursive program into a corresponding iterative program (if the language is sufficiently powerful, but not much power is required, e.g. C is powerful enough). Depending on the language, this might or might not make the program significantly longer. Likewise, it's always possible to take a program that stores data in multiple places and change it so that it uses a single array for all storage (again, assuming appropriate language features that most languages will have).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hehe, I managed to squeeze some recursion up in there if you haven't checked :-)

Comment: Another related proposal I just made: [Can you surpass Γ<sub>0</sub>?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13524#13524)  For those serious about making extremely large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Fraction Frenzy!

### Task:

Your task is to generate the list of reciprocals of the Fraction Frenzy function (`FF(n)`) given a positive integer `n`.

### Introduction:

Before I can introduce the FF function, I have to first explain Egyptian fractions.

Egyptian fractions are a way of expressing fractions as the sum of distinct unit fractions - so one way to express the fraction `5/8` is `1/2 + 1/8`. It is not other fraction sums like

```
1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8
1/2 + 1/16 + 1/16
```

because not all of their fractions are distinct (`1/4` is repeated in the first example, and `1/16` in the second).

---

The FF (Fraction Frenzy) function is described like so:

`FF(1)` is the Egyptian fraction `1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30`.

`FF(2)` is equal to `FF(1)` "multiplied" by itself (`FF(1)` "squared"):

```
  (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)
= 1/4 + 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/-60 + 1/6 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/-90 +
  1/10 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-150 + 1/-60 + 1/-90 + 1/-150 + 1/900
```

This is not a fully reduced Egyptian fraction yet, because there are "repeats" in fractions. To reduce them, the following procedure is done:

1. Sum all "like" unit fractions together.
2. Reduce the sums to their simplest forms - so for example, if a sum from step `1` is `2/6`, that can be reduced to `1/3`.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until all reciprocals are distinct.
4. If there is a pair of one positive and one negative fraction that have an equal absolute value, remove both of them (e.g. `1/-5` and `1/5` must both be removed)
5. If fractions are not unit and cannot be reduced further, split it up into unit fractions with a equal denominator, and keep one fraction as it is. With the other ones, multiply them by `(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30)`.
6. Repeat until the final fraction sum is a valid Egyptian fraction.

This is the reduction of `FF(2)`:

```
  1/4 + 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/-60 + 1/6 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/-90 +
  1/10 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-150 + 1/-60 + 1/-90 + 1/-150 + 1/900
= 1/4 + 2/6 + 1/9 + 2/10 + 2/15 + 1/25 + 2/-60 + 2/-90 + 2/-150 + 1/900 (step 1)
= 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/5 + 2/15 + 1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900   (step 2)
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/15(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/-30) +        (step 5)
  1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/30 + 1/45 + 1/75 + 1/-450 +
  1/25 + 1/-30 + 1/-45 + 1/-75 + 1/900
= 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/25 + 1/-450 + 1/900                  (step 4)
```

For all `n` (except for `1`), `FF(n)` is defined by "squaring" `FF(n-1)`.

### Input and Output:

Given an integer `n`, you must output a list all of the reciprocals of `FF(n)`, sorted in ascending order:

```
1 -> [2, 3, 5, -30]
2 -> [3, 4, 5, 9, 15, 25, -450, 900]
```

You are allowed to use a string with any delimiter, or your language's interpretation of a list.

### Specs:

- You must output the results of the `FF(n)` function exactly as specified above.
- You are guaranteed that the input will be a positive integer - it will never be below zero, and it will never be a decimal (or fraction).

Comment: ^vote, I'm trying to see if there's a non-recursive method, because currently it's O(n^2) according to the problem specs.

Comment: I think step 2 ("*Reduce the sums to their simplest forms*") needs to be more carefully specified. What is the simplest form of a given fraction?

Answer (score 0):

## Conjugate a Spanish Verb

### A Little Background

I thought up this challenge, believe it or not, in a spanish class. I was thinking how simple it is to conjugate regular spanish present tense verbs and the programmer in me told me to make a question about it on PPCG

### The Challenge

Given a regular Spanish infinitive and a subject, conjugate the infinitive in the present. [How to do such a thing.](http://www.wikihow.com/Conjugate-Spanish-Verbs-(Present-Tense)) For the sake of simplicity assume that all of the verbs are regular infinitives not irregular, stem-changing or reflexive.

### Rules

-The input may be given in any reasonable format

```
subject verb | verb subject| subject,verb | ["subject", "verb"] etc.
```

-If the input is not valid you may output anything or nothing at all

-The input is not valid if

```
a) It does not contain a regular, spanish, infinitive verb or a Spanish subject

b) It is not in the appropriate format, which you must specify
```

-The output can have any capitalization and is alowed trailing whitespace

### Test Cases

Assume the input is given as "verb, subject" (Without the quotes)

```
comer, yo              --> como
ir, vosotros           --> Anything (Irregular)
jugar, ellas           --> Anything (Stem Changing)
                       --> Anything (Empty)
gsmkhnjkgn, tu         --> Anything (Not a verb)
sacar, ésdfgs          --> Anything (Not a subject)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this [has been asked before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24182/194) and so would be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Goal**

Take 3 inputs, and output truey or falsey depending on whether or not they make an multiplication/division fact family.  (2 * 4 = 8, 4 * 2 = 8, 8 / 2 = 4, 8 / 4 = 2) Order does not matter, as long as in some way the three numbers make an fact family.  Repeated numbers are allowed.

**Truey Inputs**

```
2 4 8 
100 20 5 
7 7 49
```

**Falsey Inputs**

```
7 8 9
12 3 0
512 600 73
```

**Rules**
 The values should be passed to the program as parameters or variables.  Expect that only positive integers, and only 3 of them, will be passed to the program.  You may write either a full program or a function, which either prints or returns the result.  This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing challenge (the reason why it was closed on main)

Comment: Were you going to change this to multiplication/division families?

Comment: Changed it up.  I also removed my first one from the main.

Comment: Will the input numbers always be nonnegative integers?

Comment: Edited Question

Comment: IMO changing `+` to `*` and `/2` to `sqrt` doesn't make this a different question and it's still a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

### ACME (Let's Encrypt) client

[cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) [networking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[A list of ACME clients](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) already looks a bit like a PPCG leaderboard, but I don't see the typical esolang roster there. Let's Augment.

The task is in minimum number of bytes get a valid certificate for specified domain (assuming running from a directory that is accessible from web server of this domain. Or just also embedding a web server.).

Comment: Shall usage of `openssl` (libary or binary) be allowed or it should be a "hard mode" puzzle?

Comment: What does "*assuming running from a directory that is accessible from web server of this domain*" mean? That we can assume Apache / nginx / lighttpd / whatever is set up to execute our script?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, No. The script contacts ACME server, gets challenge, writes it to current directory. Then ACME server downloads the file (using pre-existing web server configured for this directory) and replies with a signed certificate, which we should save or print.

Comment: Follow-up questions: 1. Which version of ACME? 2. Which parts must be supported? 3. What will the inputs to the client be? I'm sure that detailed reading of the ACME spec will throw up more questions.

Comment: 1. -> To discretion of the answerer, 2. -> HTTP challenge. Some minimal mode to get the cert. 3. -> Domain name.

Answer (score 0):

## What I'm Planning to Post:

Print the number of **bytes** (not characters, bytes) in the program, without hardcoding the number (i.e. code like `print(8)` is not allowed).

If the code is added to (e.g. with a comment) it should change automatically without needing to change anything else.

Example (un-golfed) program in **Python 3**:

```
file = open(__file__)
data = file.read()
print(data)
file.close()
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

## What I Want to Check/Know:

1. Does this count as [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)?
2. Has this already been done? To what extent do the rules of a 'Duplicate' question apply here? (I have done some searching...)
3. What should my challenge title be? I cannot think of any fitting ones.
4. Should I include the example (un-golfed) program in my post, or does that make it too easy?

Comment: Thanks for posting in the Sandbox first. Why is hard-coding banned? If the code is added to, hardcoding may or may not help, so I don't see much point in banning this. Also, your code is wrong; that's a false-quine, not the program length.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to put a `len()` in there too. Hard-coding is banned because in many esolangs, a single byte will just output the simple integer `1` (or similar).

Comment: But if you edit the program to add comments, that program will stop working.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Thanks for using the sandbox. I *swear* we've had a challenge similar to this, but I can't seem to find it. I'll keep looking.

Comment: This wouldn't be a kolmogorov-complexity. That tag is for outputting some constant, predefined string. Including an example implementation is fine, it's fairly common practice, but usually it contains a very naive or brute-force algorithm for the problem that wouldn't actually make a good solution (even when golfed).

Comment: Yes, it has been done: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/27079/194

Answer (score 0):

## Roman Dates

The Romans measured dates based on three days every month:
The Kalends, or the 1st
The Nones, which was usually on the 5th,
and the Ides, which was usually on the 13th.

In March, May, July, and October the Ides and Nones fall two days later, on the 7th and 15th.

### Months

There are two forms of the months that matter for this challenge:
Ablative:

1. Ianuariis
2. Februriis
3. Martiis
4. Aprilibus
5. Maiis
6. Iuniis
7. Iuliis
8. Augustis
9. Septembribus
10. Octobribus
11. Novembribus
12. Decembribus

And Accusative:

1. Ianuarias
2. Februarias
3. Martias
4. Apriles
5. Maias
6. Iunias
7. Iulias
8. Augustas
9. Septembres
10. Octobres
11. Novembres
12. Decembres

### Calculation of dates

On the day of one of them, they used the ablative of the day (Kalendis, nonis, or Idibus) combined with the ablative of the month (e.g. Idibus martiis)

One day before one of them they used pridie with the accusative of the day (Kalendas, Nonas, and Idus) and month (e.g. pridie nones septembres)

The Romans calculated the date as how many days until the next one of these, counting inclusively.  They used a.d. and the number of days until the next one in lowercase roman numerals, and then the day and month in accusative (e.g. a.d. xxii Kalendas Iulias)

### Years

The years are counted since the Founding of the city of Rome in 753 B.C.E., with A.U.C. appended to the end of it.

http://novaroma.org/nr/Roman_dates

The challenge is, give an input of a day, month, and year in any preferred format, to return a string given the Roman date.

As this is code-golf, the code with the shortest bytes wins, and the standard loopholes are disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematical Creativity

At our workplace we are so creative that sometimes we decide that today the number `2=9`, `0=231` or `67=5`... just for the sake of it. So for that day everyone in the workplace must consider that fact.

Your task is to write a full program or function that takes as input today's value of the decided number, which operation to perform and output the result, of course the new number's value affects also the result.

**Input:**

1. Only positive integers `>= 0`and `<= 1000000`.
2. The math operations to perform are only sum `+`, subtraction `-` or multiplication `*`.
3. The input is taken from standard input in any reasonable format for example: `[N V X + Y]`, `N,V,X,+,Y`, `NVX+Y`, `("N","V","X","+","Y")`, `['N','V','X','+','Y']`, etc.
4. First parameter `N` is the choosen number.
5. Second parameter `V` is new value of `N`.
6. Third parameter `X` is the first number of the math operation.
7. Fourth parameter is the math operation to perfom, can be only `+`, `-`, `*`.
8. Fifth parameter `Y` is the second number of the math operation.

**Explained example:**

1. Input `5,27,252,+,3`.
2. All the `5`'s becomes `27` so `254+3 -> 2272+3=2275` but the result is `2275`, it contains `5` so it becomes `22727`.
3. No recursive substitution or infinite loop is needed. The substitution must be performed only once on `X,Y` and on the result.

**Example inputs / outputs:**

```
Input              > Output
----------------------------------------------
5,27,252,+,3       > 2272+3=22727 
45,0,237456,-,4567 > 23706-067=23639
9,7,349,*,7        > 347*7=2427
121,1,1212121,+,0  > 121+0=1
5,55,555,+,5555    > 555555+55555555=556111110
10,5,11000,*,10    > 1500*5=7500
1,2,3,+,4          > 3+4=7
4,4,3,+,4          > 3+4=7
```

**Rules**

1. The number substitution must be performed only once on the first two numbers `X,Y` and only once on the final result. No recursive substitution or infinite loops are needed.
2. The output must contain the full math operation, not only the final result, for example: `2272+3=22727`.
3. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
4. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

---

**Sandbox questions:**

1. Is this a duplicate of another question? I thought it would already exist but couldn't find any challenge by searching. If you know of it please let me know.
2. Is the input enough clear or is it possible to improve in some way?
3. Is the challenge clear?
4. Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)
5. Suggestion for title?

Comment: Should the substitution be performed only once, or once for each occurrence, or recursively until no occurrence remains? Consider, for example, `121,1,1212121,+,0`. Then you should also specify what happens with infinite loops. Compare with [this proposal](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11544/32014) and my comment there.

Comment: What will the output be for input `5,55,555,+,5555`?

Comment: @Zgarb thanks for pointing that out, only one-time substitution is needed on the first numbers and the result, no recursivity or loops. I added your example in the test cases.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I added your suggested example in the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Milking the cows

When I was a kid, we used to play a card game called "Milking the cows". I have *no* idea why it was called that, as it had nothing to do with said activity, but whatever. For months we would play furiously, seeing who was best at this game.

It wasn't until years later that I realized the game is completely deterministic. All my hours of practice turned out to have been pointless. But now it does make for an interesting code-golf.

### Rules of the game

There are two players. Each is dealt half of a standard pack of shuffled cards. Every round, both players draw the top two cards from their respective decks and compare values. The highest scoring pair wins, and that player adds all captured cards to his stack of cards (at the bottom).
In case of a draw, both players draw one additional card and compare again (If this is again a draw, another card is drawn, etc)

The game continues with both sides drawing cards until one player is unable to draw another card, at which point they lose and their opponent wins the game.

Card values are equal to the printed number for number cards, Aces are 11 points and J/Q/K are all 10.

### The challenge

Given an input string of 52 characters representing the cards (without suit, since it doesn't matter in this game), deal the first 26 to player 1, the rest to player 2, and then determine who wins that match of Milking the cows.

The characters sent are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K,A for the numbers, Ten, Jack, Queen, King and Ace. It can be assumed that the input string is  correct and contains *exactly* 4 of each character.

The top of the stack is on the right side; the bottom of the stack is on the left side. Cards are always drawn or put back on the bottom *one at a time*

When a round is won, cards are added to the bottom of the winner's stack, starting with the opponent's cards and then the own cards, in the order they were drawn.

When the winner is determined, output the number of the player that won. It is possible (but phenomenally unlikely) for the game to end in a draw, because *both* players are unable to draw a card. In this case, output 0.

### Example of a round:

> Player 1's stack: QTKJ42336K59QKJ77T8J953485
>
> Player 2's stack: JTK676ATQ8A576429Q2A948A23
>
> Player 1 draws: 5, 8
>
> Player 2 draws: 3, 2
>
> Player 1 wins the round (13 points vs 5)
>
> Player 1's new stack: 8523QTKJ42336K59QKJ77T8J9534
>
> Player 2's new stack: JTK676ATQ8A576429Q2A948A

### Testcases:

```
69K9A9QJ8TT33A88KQ685J97AQK224Q2726T73547K6J554J4AT3 -> 2
98JK947A5K283A5A2TAJ6K278T4TQT73674Q956JK94Q68QJ3352 -> 2
9T87J2K38KJT846558A2Q4A95395T67936A7Q2J4TQAK623JKQ74 -> 1
J67835828K48KA45TQ546JQ479TA2JT2Q933K27JT69KA9735QA6 -> 1
23456789TJQKA23456789TJQKA23456789TJQKA23456789TJQKA -> 0
```

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Thanks for using the sandbox. Can you elaborate a bit on what makes this much different than [Determine the winner of a game of War](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82340/42963)? Is it just the fact that the top two cards are compared instead of only the top card?

Comment: Ah, they're very similar indeed - I didn't know this game had different names in other languages. The biggest difference is probably checking for ties (which almost never happens) but I'm not sure if it's worth a new challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert to polynomial base numbers

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

---

## Background

#### Base Representation

Bases may be written with the following generalization (let concatenation just represent adjacency in digits; `10 = ab` when `a = 1, b = 0`):

```
abcdex = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx^1 + ex^0
```

Essentially, we can write in any base we want such that the last digit is base to the power 0, penultimate digit is base to the power 1, etc. When we make the base a variable (`x`), we can represent a polynomial with a number.

#### Representation Overflow

Let's take our example before with `abcdex`. What happens when our representation for numbers (base 10 for our case) becomes too large to represent with a single character? Why, we use the tilda (`~`) on both sides of the value.

Thus, if we had the conditions `a = 9, b = 32, c = 2, d = 43, e = 10` and were restricted to writing with base 10 representations for each value, our number may be represented as `9~32~2~43~~10~x`.

#### Minimized Polynomials

For this challenge, I will occasionally refer to "Minimized Polynomials". When I say this, I mean that there will be no spaces in the polynomial string, terms with coefficients of zero will not be shown, and polynomials will be written in terms of greatest term first.

For example, the following is *not* a minimized polynomial:

```
x^2 + x^0 + 5 * x^4 + 0x^1
```

The following is the first example's minimized form:

```
5x^4+1x^2+1x^0
```

## The Task

Given a valid minimized polynomial string input `n`, write a function or program which returns or prints the polynomial base representation of the value in base 10, allowing for representation overflow.

## Examples

Let `f` be the function described in the task:

```
>>> f("1x^4+1x^3+1x^2+1x^1+1x^0")
1111

>>> f("6x^3+1x^1+5x^0")
6015

>>> f("20x^4+4x^3+1x^1")
~20~4010

>>> f("300x^6+30x^4+40x^3+2x^2+1x^0")
~300~0~30~~40~201
```

Comment: The introduction seems backwards to me. I think that what it's trying to express is that by representing numbers in base `b` you can show a bijection between the ring of natural numbers `N` and the ring of polynomials over the integers modulo `b`, `(Z/bZ)[x]`, but that's not what it really communicates. In particular, "*we can represent a polynomial with a number*" seems to be talking about an injection `Z[x] -> N` (or maybe `Z[x] -> Z`), and while they do exist they're more complicated than anything described in this question.

Comment: In fact, the section on overflow explains why the ideas in the introduction break down. Once the coefficients cease to be elements of `0..b-1` base conversion gives aliasing. The workaround of introducing tildes means that what you have is no longer a base-`b` number, so the title is wrong.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have no idea what your first comment is saying. Is your second comment suggesting that I rename this to "Convert minimized polynomial to shorthand polynomial" or similar?

Comment: Really the whole stuff about base conversion is a red herring: the task consists in parsing a polynomial, filling in the zero coefficients, and then rendering them with conditional wrapping in tildes.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiplication puzzle using digits 1-9

The puzzle is to use the digits 1-9 inclusive, exactly once, to fill in the blanks such that:

> _  _  _  _  *  3  =  _  _  _  _  _

Your task is to create the shortest program that finds all solutions to the equation.

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

Comment: Is this exactly 4 characters `* 3 = ` 5 characters? or is this any amount * 3 = any amount?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's a 4 digit int multiplied by 3 = a 5 digit int

Comment: You should give the output list for reference. Submissions can hardcode an output, so if there's few solutions, you should change the problem so that there's many.

Comment: There are two solutions. It's not clear what output format is expected, but if `5823 5832` is acceptable output then hardcoding that is likely to be much shorter than any approach which uses calculation.

Comment: Should I edit the rules to say that the solutions can't be hardcoded and that the program must output both the 4 and 5 digit numbers?

Comment: You could for example change the hardcoded 3 to a number N which should be received as input. This way hardcoding the output becomes much less desirable. EDIT: Actually, I don't know if this puzzle also has solutions for other values of N

Comment: @Leo, yes, and it has loads for N=8. That's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## Hex address to little endian escaped string

You are a brilliant hacker and you just gained access to a unprotected computer! To complete your exploitation, you need to convert a set of hexadecimal addresses into a different format.

You remember your lessons from university and you find out the machine you're on is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), meaning the order of the bytes is "reversed".

To make a break from your illegal activity, you decide to code a little program that does that automatically.

## The Goal

Convert a string of the form

```
0x12345678
```

to

```
\x78\x56\x34\x12
```

You set up a few tests and their potential results:

```
0x080483b4   =>   \xb4\x83\x04\x08
0x00000fff   =>   \xff\x0f\x00\x00
0xfffffff0   =>   \xf0\xff\xff\xff
0xefbeadde   =>   \xde\xad\xbe\xef
```

## Rules

The input is of the form `0xXXXXXXXX` and the output must be of the form `\xXX\xXX\xXX\xXX`. The input will always be 10 chars long and the output must be 16 chars long.

The score is the number of bytes used to write the encoding function.
If the input string appears in the solution (i.e. not passed as an argument) it is not taken into account. The display of the result is implied (e.g. no need to `print`, `puts`, ...).

Comment: Is this question trying to allow snippets? That's not normally what we do here, so if you want it, you'll have to be explicit about specifically what sort of programs are accepted. If it's unintentional, see [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/62131) for our normal I/O standards (you can link that in your question if you like), and ask for a "program or function"; note that your example solution isn't a program or a function, so it would need changing. (You probably don't need to give an example solution at all, though; and if you have one, you can post it as an answer.)

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, I need to make the type of code more explicit? I wasn't sure how to make it work for all languages, ... Also I'm not sure about needing the `return` statement for this challenge, nor the `print` ... What do you think? I'll remove the example for later, thanks :)

Comment: The problem is more that we have a lot of standard rules already that go into a *lot* of detail on what's allowed and what isn't, because they're too complex to really fit into one post. The way your question is worded, you're trying to override that (i.e. allow things that are disallowed by the rules), which means that you'd need to go to a lot more effort to explain exactly what's allowed and what isn't. You can certainly override the standard rules if there's a good reason, but it's rather more complex than just going along with them.

Answer (score 0):

## Starry Starry Night

This challenge needs a lot of work in my opinion, especially refining rules on input-output, I want to leave it as open as possible, while excluding unfair methods such as pre-drawn graphs etc.

some parts of this are currently extremely vague, please ask any questions you believe might be important.

i'll be adding some graphics in to help explain what the challenge is about at a glance though.

---

Does anyone else sometimes looks up at the stars and ponder the great mathematical questions of our time, Does P=NP if you just want to check a bus timetable, can a 'try/catch' block solve the halting problem, and how far would that star need to move to form an equilateral triangle..

---

given an array of 6 numbers, consisting of 3 arrays containing two numbers between 0-255 each, i.e.

```
[[35,185],[141,8],[192,223]]
```

return the change required to be made to a single point, to have the three points form an equilateral triangle.

Input-

- Can be taken as 6 distinct integers, an array of arrays, a single array, or a set of three objects with x/y as named/default properties,

  - these input formats are loose and whatever best suits your language should be used, within reason (i.e. - mathematica cannot use a pre-drawn graph as input)
- no two points will be on the same x/y, and 0 will never appear as any single x or y co-ordinate

Output-

- Only one out of the three co-ordinates can be modified, the other two must remain unchanged
- Can be given graphically on a grid, a returned 'modified' version of the original input, or as an output of the values changed (i.e. 40->55;30->99)
- you're looking up at the sky, your numbers can easily be off by a bit, the returned values are only required to be accurate to the whole number, rounding up or down is allowed
- you do not have to achieve the smallest distance, or smallest/largest resulting triangle, any mathematically equilateral triangle will be correct

Examples:(still have to actually calculate these)

`[[20,113],[63,17],[40,161]]
[[43,119],[183,197],[103,86]]
[[144,216],[108,203],[113,199]]
[[197,131],[217,7],[13,77]]
[[100,60],[26,107],[130,241]]
[[209,61],[208,98],[47,94]]
[[48,78],[179,135],[52,119]]
[[93,148],[124,226],[137,118]]
[[65,21],[168,167],[221,56]]
[[89,118],[48,181],[29,98]]`

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: When you say "*rounding is not strict, and can be 1 number either side of a resulting decimal value*" does that mean that the output can be a whole number obtained by rounding up or down?

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's correct, i'll clarify it a bit further, would `the returned values are only required to be accurate to the whole number, rounding up or down is allowed` be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. The really ambiguous part was "*1 number*", where it wasn't clear how many decimal places were expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Associativity Conversion

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[syntax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)[balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string)

Operators that aren't [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) usually come with some implicit associativity which let you omit parentheses in some expressions for readability. E.g. for a left-associative operator `$`, the following parentheses are assumed:

```
a $ b $ c $ d ≡ ((a $ b) $ c) $ d
```

But for a right-associative operator, the implied parentheses are these:

```
a $ b $ c $ d ≡ a $ (b $ (c $ d))
```

For this challenge, we will use an "invisible" operator (that is, we'll simply write `abcd` for `((ab)c)d` or `a(b(cd))`). Your task is to take some valid expression of that operator as input, where the operator will be assumed to be left-associative. You should then output an equivalent expression, where the operator is assumed to be right-associative.

### Example

Consider the input:

```
a(bc)(d(efg))
```

First, let's insert all parentheses that are implied by the operator's left-associativity:

```
(a(bc))(d((ef)g))
```

Now we want to rewrite this in a right-associative fashion. Therefore, we drop all parentheses start at the right end of a subexpression:

```
(abc)d(ef)g
```

We cannot remove any further parentheses because that would change the implied parentheses.

### ToDo

small print and test cases

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to correct "*Therefore, we drop all parentheses start at the right end of a subexpression*". To make it parse it would suffice to change *start* to *starting*, but doesn't every parenthesis start at the right end of a subexpression? Perhaps it would be simpler to just add a tree diagram instead of adding parentheses?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess I meant "starting at the right end of the surrounding subexpression" but that's not much clearer. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Triangular Numbers

Compute the nth triangular number. Triangular numbers are the number of things in a size x triangle (`n(n+1)/2`).

Testcases:

```
0 0
1 1
2 3
3 6
7 28
34 595
```

IO in any allowed form, standard loopholes apply.

Comment: This would make for an interesting challenge, but the question is highly unlikely to receive many upvotes without more explanation (clearer spec, test-cases, the definition of the triangular numbers, etc. The definition is important because we require that challenges should require as little knowledge/research to solve as possible)

Comment: Also, this is a subset of [Polygonal Numbers!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99688/42545) (though that may not matter as there may be different golfy approaches in various languages, and also that challenge wasn't taken very well and has few answers)

Answer (score 0):

## Unschedule my tasks

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

### Intro

I have a scheduler that uses priority scheduling on my PC so there are several tasks with a definite priority. All that i still remember is that every task runs cyclically
forever with an also definite period.
I can see which tasks are running from `t=0` to now, but i need to know the priority and the period time of every task.

### Input

The input is a string with the length `n` showing the last `n` timestamps. We give the tasks uppercase letters from `A...Z`, where the amount of different tasks `k` is given as `0<k<27`. If one tasks is chosen, it will need one time stamp long to finish and will start after it's period time `T` again.
Example:

```
not given:
task A: priority=2, T=7
task B: priority=1, T=2
task C: priority=3, T=5

results in:
A      A      A      A      A      A      A
B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C
_____________________________________________
BABCBCBAB BCB BABCB BABCBCB BABCB BABCB BCBA
```

The last line will be your input and the goal is to get every task with the corresponding priority and period time.

### Output

So for the input

```
BABCBCBAB BCB BABCB BABCBCB BABCB BABCB BCBA
```

You should output

```
A 2 7
B 1 2
C 3 5
```

The output should have the format `[task name] [priority] [period time]` with one task per line.

### Rules

1. All tasks will always start at t=0
2. If multiple tasks are ready to run, the one with the lower priority will run first, the other one will move one slot to the right
3. The priority of one task is always the same, so no dynamic priorities will be used
4. The processor will never have to run at 100%, or as formula: `1/TA + 1/TB + ... + 1/Tk < 1`. In the example it's `1/7 + 1/2 + 1/5 = 0.84 < 1`
5. If there are multiple solutions, output only one of them
6. The input string will show every task at least 3 times

### Test cases

```
in:
A  A  A  A
out:
A 1 3

in:
CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA
out:
A 3 6
B 2 6
C 1 6

in: 
//A      A      A      A      A      A
//B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
//C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C
//D             D             D
//E        E        E        E        E
  ABCDBCEABEC B ACBDE BAC BC EABCDB  ABCE
out:
A 1 7
B 2 4
C 3 5
D 4 14
E 5 9
```

### Thoughts

Still thinking about turning the question around. Just turning input and output around but i like this way more because i think it's more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

## Ultimatum Game

You and a (not so) friendly bot have a chance to play a game. There is 100 dollars on the table. One person, suggests a split, and the other can accept the split, or force each individual to accept absolutely nothing. You will alternate being able to give the ultimatum for a substantially large number (1000) rounds. This process will proceed in a round robin fashion till every bot has played all the others exactly once. Your score in this manner, will just be the total amount of money you collect.

Now your job is to write a bot that will play this game. You will be provided with needed information as command line arguments.

A sample invocation will look like this if you are giving the ultimatum. When you receive an invocation like this, you would be the one propsing a split.

```
foolanguage myBot.foo 4 ultimatum 1 reject 10 reject 20 reject 25 accept
```

Or, like this if you are the one considering the ultimatum. You will be tasked with either accepting the split, or rejecting it (both bots get 0).

```
foolanguage myBot.foo 4 accepting 1 reject 10 reject 20 reject 25 accept 1
```

The first number represents the number of rounds played (n). The second will be a string either "Ultimatum" or accept/ reject. Next will follow 2n+1 strings. The first 2n will be offers and what the choice was. The last string will be the current offer.

---

### Entering

You will provide a command stem and a unique bot name. 
So the sample bot can be called fooBot, and the command stem (after which arguments are appended) looks like "foolanguage myBot.foo"

Your bot will then output either the number it will offer, or (if they are the one who has to consider the offer), ("a" for accept/ "r" for reject) within 50 ms.

Your bot must be be able to make both choices (accept or reject). No locking in to just one choice.

Also, your bot must be deterministic (prng's may be seeded with a private seed. If you wish to do this, insert a dummy seed, and change it right before the competition) please publish the hash to ensure you don't tweak it in light of other submissions.

In the spirit of fair competition, no access to the file system (or OS calls). I will allow the option to write to a maximum of one text file which can have a maximum size of 8 megabytes. Solutions will be tested within a virtual machine imaged with the latest version of linux on my home desktop which has an Intel i7-4770 quad core 3.4 gHZ cpu.

Comment: I believe we already have had a [prisoners](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26486/prisoners-dilemma-v-2-battle-royale) [dilemma](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/1p5-iterated-prisoners-dilemma?noredirect=1&lq=1) KOTH...

Comment: @LliwTelracs I do believe the strategy here is entirely different, and brings up some interesting effects. Most notably, the asymmetry of the situation, and the information which you have.

Comment: 1. I suggest rewriting the input spec to pass via stdin instead of the command line. Some shells have command line length limits: e.g. on most versions of Windows you'll only be able to get up to about 820 rounds with the current format. Using stdin would also allow newlines, which would make the format easier for humans to read and understand. Also, what does the `accepting` in the second example mean? 2. I presume that the score is the total amount of money you make over all rounds and all games, but this should be made explicit.

Comment: I fear this challenge would be dominated by bots offering a 99/1 split and accepting any offer of at least 1 dollar, with no consideration for the history

Comment: @Leo I plan on creating a few sample bots, which will mimic human behavior. For example, one bot might reject offers less than 25. Another, might grew more and more likely to reject offers based on the average money allocated. Another might only offer (and accept) splits of 50/50 (or better). This way, good solutions will cater to such bots.

Comment: I was going to write a 50/50 bot, so I would be sad if that's already taken by a sample bot - unless the samples are clearly only for development and not participating in the final contest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor sure, I could make it that way, sample bots are only for developement

Answer (score 0):

## Board Game Breaking - The Front Nine W.I.P.

Eventually I will make a post here for each of the challenges. This post is for discussing them as a series. If you have an idea for a good board game breaker, please share!

### Introduction

Board Game Breaking is a series of challenges that harness computing power in order to 'break' a game (i.e. ensure no one will play with you). Each challenge will revolve around creating a tool that analyzes the board game in a way that will give you some advantage. There are [nine challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) total.

#### [BGB #1 - Number Rings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11648/43214)

- Input: Int
- Output: Likelihood of creating that int with `3d6` & `+-*/`

[image: Number Rings]

#### [BGB #2 - Can't Stop!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11649/43214)

- Input: 1-3 Ints
- Output: Likehood 2 (of 4) d6 will add up to one of the inputs

[image: Can't Stop]

#### BGB #3 - Axis & Allies

- Input: # of units on each side
- Output: Probability of winning the fight

[image: Axis & Allies]

#### BGB #4 - Labrynth

- Input: Image
- Output: Image re-arranged in labrynth-like way to make gradient

[image: Labrynth]

#### BGB #5 - Scrabble

- Input: Word list
- Output: Word with most subwords

[image: Scrabble]

#### BGB #6 - ??

#### BGB #7 - ??

#### BGB #8 - ??

#### BGB #9 - ??

Answer (score 0):

## BGB #1 - Number Rings

**Goal**: Take an int, output the probability of creating that int with `3d6` & `+-*/`.

[image: Number Rings]

### Introduction

*Check [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)*

### Background

Number Rings (or Sector 18) is a board game where up to 4 players take turns rolling a set of 3 six-sided dice. Then then using `+-*/` to combine *all* three of those numbers to get a number, `x`. They then place (or remove) a ring on a `x` peg. First player to have a ring on each of his pegs, wins. That is the basic idea of how the game works.

For any number `a`, I want to know the probability that I will be able to create `a` with a random roll.

### Specification

- Input

  - One integer, `i`, such that `0<i<19`
  - The input is flexible
- Output

  - The probability of being able to create `i` with a random roll
  - At least `5` digits of accuracy
  - Ex: `0.12345`. `.12345`, `12.345`
  - Or exact rational number
  - Ex: `145/1023`
  - Leading/Trailing whitespace is acceptable
- Scoring

  - Shortest program/function in bytes wins

### Test Cases

*ToDo*

Comment: This is basically a loop through a Cartesian product wrapped around http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32085/194 and is borderline dupe.

Answer (score 0):

## BGB #2 - Can't Stop!

*Goal*: Take 3 ints, output the probability 2 of 4d6 will sum to one of the ints.

[image: Can't Stop]

### Introduction

*Check [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)*

### Background

Can't Stop is a board game. There are columns for the numbers `2` through `12`, each having a number of rungs that must be climbed into to win the column. On a player's turn, they receive 3 white pieces and `4d6`. They roll the dice, sum two of the values and either move a placed white piece up a rung or place a white piece in a column. First player to win 3 columns, wins the game.

For any numbers, `a` or `a,b` or `a,b,c`, I want to know the probability that I will roll at least two numbers that sum to `a`, `b` or `c`

### Specification

- Input

  - One to three integers between `2` and `12` inclusive
  - Taking 3 integers that aren't necessarily distinct is also acceptable
  - The input is flexible
- Output

  - The probability of being able to create one of the inputs with a random roll
  - At least 5 digits of accuracy
  - Ex: `0.12345`, `.12345`, `12.345`
  - Or exact rational number
  - Ex: `145/1023`
  - Leading/Trailing whitespace is acceptable
- Scoring

  - Shortest program/function in bytes wins

### Test Cases

*ToDo*

Comment: What about output as exact rational number? Is input flexible enough to say that there are always three numbers but they don't have to be distinct?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Great questions! Yes to both. I modified the challenge to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Penrose Triangle Codegolf**

The Penrose triangle, also known as the Penrose tribar, or the impossible tribar, is an impossible object. - [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle)

The goal in this challenge is to display a Penrose triangle in the fewest bytes possible.

**Rules:**

1. You must display the Penrose Triangle digitally after generating it.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Rule 2 is unnecessary because it applies [by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/194). Rule 1 is a disaster which is guaranteed to prompt arguments over which minimalist ASCII art answers actually represent a Penrose triangle.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

## Schedule my tasks

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

### Intro

Inverse challenge to **Unschedule my tasks**.

I don't have a scheduler that uses priority scheduling on my PC but i want one. I have several tasks which all start at `t=0` and each has a priority and a period time. So your task is to schedule my tasks.

### Input

The input is a string including the different tasks, the priority and the period time of each task. We give the tasks uppercase letters from `A...Z`, where the amount of different tasks `k` is given as `0<k<27`. If one tasks is chosen, it will need one time stamp long to finish and will start after it's period time `T` again. The input has the format `[task name] [priority] [period time]` with one task per line.
Example:

```
A 2 7
B 1 2
C 3 5
```

### Output

So for the input

```
A 2 7
B 1 2
C 3 5
```

you should output (only the last line):

```
A      A      A      A      A      A      A
B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C
_____________________________________________
BABCBCBAB BCB BABCB BABCBCB BABCB BABCB BCBA
```

### Rules

1. All tasks will always start at t=0
2. If multiple tasks are ready to run, the one with the lower priority will run first, the other one will move one slot to the right
3. The priority of one task is always the same, so no dynamic priorities will be used
4. The processor will never have to run at 100%, or as formula: `1/TA + 1/TB + ... + 1/Tk < 1`. In the example it's `1/7 + 1/2 + 1/5 = 0.84 < 1`
5. If there are multiple solutions, output only one of them
6. The output string has to show every task at least 3 times, but the the output has to be finite
7. Priority and period time are unsigned integers in the range `0<x<50`

### Test cases

```
in:
A 1 3
out:
A  A  A  A

in:
A 3 6
C 1 6
B 2 6
out:
CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA   CBA

in:
A 1 7
B 2 4
C 3 5
D 4 14
E 5 9
out: 
//A      A      A      A      A      A
//B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
//C    C    C    C    C    C    C    C
//D             D             D
//E        E        E        E        E
  ABCDBCEABEC B ACBDE BAC BC EABCDB  ABCE
```

Answer (score 0):

## Creative Title about the Moser-de Bruijn

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### The Challenge

Calculate the [Moser-de Bruijn (A000695)](https://oeis.org/A000695) sequence for all integers up to the input value N.

Each term of the sequence is defined as the sum of distinct powers of four arranged in ascending order. This means in base 4 every number of the sequence only has ones or zeroes.

You are to print a list of the sequence where all values are less than N. Output is to be separated by either commas, tabs, or spaces. Trailing/Leading commas or whitespace are not permitted. having a comma followed by whitespace is allowed, but the reverse is not. You must use standard output for your language. You are to take input from your language's standard input. Exclude the sequence's first term of zero as it isn't relevant to the game's rules. You may assume the input will always be a positive non-zero integer.

## Test Cases

```
5  => 1,4
6  => 1 4 5
22 => 1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, 21
1105 => 1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 64, 65, 68, 69, 80, 81, 84, 85, 256, 257, 260, 261, 272, 273, 276, 277, 320, 321, 324, 325, 336, 337, 340, 341, 1024, 1025, 1028, 1029, 1040, 1041, 1044, 1045, 1088, 1089, 1092, 1093, 1104
```

### Sandbox Notes

This is my first challenge, so input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The stuff about "subtract a square" is completely irrelevant and distracting. After reading the introduction I expected the challenge to be finding the best move given the current size of the pile. IMO it would be a notable improvement to remove all mention of the game and just talk about the sequence which the question is actually about.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Equivalently, this challenge is to find all integers up to `N` whose base-4 representation contains only 0s and 1s. Include this explicitly?

Comment: @GregMartin Good idea, I'll add that in!

Answer (score 0):

## You Jelly?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In this code challenge you are here to explain Jelly code for us simple-minded plebeians. To simplify things we are working in a restricted subset of Jelly.

### Details

The input will be a Jelly leading constant chain matching the regex `/([01H+] )+/. For full explanation, see the [Jelly tutorial](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial), but as a quick summary each symbol in Jelly represents a function with an arity of 0 (is a *nilad*), 1 (a *monad*) or 2 (a *dyad*). A *chain* is a sequence of symbols. A *leading constant chain* is a chain whose first element is a nilad and is followed by any number of subsequences that are any of a monad, a dyad followed by a nilad or a nilad followed by a dyad. Jelly is parsed left to right.

As implied by the regex restriction, the source consists of four symbols: `0`, a nilad whose value is the integer 0; 1, a nilad whose value is the integer 1; `H`, a monad whose value is the function `x -> x / 2`; or `+`, a dyad whose value is the function `x, y -> x + y`.

A leading constant chain over the above symbols is evaluated into an equivalent infix formula by the following rules (where `$d` represents 1 or 2).

```
eval("$d $chain") = eval_i("$chain", "$d")
eval_i(""           , expr) = expr
eval_i("+ $d $chain", expr) = eval_i("$chain", "($expr + $d)")
eval_i("$d + $chain", expr) = eval_i("$chain", "($d + $expr)")
eval_i("H $chain"   , expr) = eval_i("$chain", "($d / 2)")
```

Your task is to take a Jelly program under the following restrictions (only the three symbols above used, always separated by exactly a single space and forming a leading constant chain) and to output a string representing a traditional infix-notation representation of the input. The output of your solution may be equivalent the specified output up to whitespace and PEMDAS rules (i.e. parentheses may be dropped when it does not change the meaning).

### Examples

```
Jelly Program ->      Infix Notation
1             ->                   1
0 H           ->             (0 / 2)
1 0 +         ->             (0 + 1)
1 + 0         ->             (1 + 0)
0 H 1 +       ->       (1 + (0 / 2))
1 1 + H       ->       ((1 + 1) / 2)
1 0 + + 0     ->       ((0 + 1) + 0)
1 0 + H + 0   -> (((0 + 1) / 2) + 0)
```

### Judging

This is code-golf, so lowest byte count wins. Standard loopholes are disallowed. Standard input-output formats (function-or-program) are in play.

Comment: "You Jelly?" is not >= 15 characters, unfortunately

Comment: @MistahFiggins oh drat :P. I created this challenge entirely for the title...

Comment: "Are you Jelly?" is 14... maybe a sneaky space or question mark

Answer (score 0):

### Lost in Space: Help me get back to civilisation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your spaceship's radio receives a transmission from an unknown location:

> ```
> To anyone who picks up this transmission, I need help!
> My hyperdrive malfunctioned during a routine jump to 
> the PPCG Planet. I survived the drop from hyperspace,
> but now my ship's positioning system is broken. And 
> worse, I can't seem to access Hyperdrives Stack
> Exchange to fix it!
>
> I've tried to triangulate my position using local
> satellites. I can send a 'ping' to them, and then the
> satellite will report how long the ping took to reach
> it. But the results don't make any sense! Some of the
> satellites must be broken and are feeding me false
> data...
>
> I've attached the read-out of all the satellites I
> pinged to this transmission. Can you work out which
> ones are faulty?
> ```

You examine the data that was attached to the transmission. Your spaceship's computer analyses the data and notes that it is a list of tuples, each tuple which contains:

1. The known position of a satellite as a coordinate pair;
2. The distance from the lost spaceship that that satellite reported.

A majority of satellite data will support the spaceship being at a certain location -- this is the correct location of the lost spaceship. Write a program or function that outputs this location.

**Sample Inputs and Outputs**

todo

Answer (score 0):

## Battle of the Algorithms, Kruskal vs Prim

This will be a challenge similar to a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.  There will be two threads each with a winner.

This challenge is about [minimum spanning trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).  I might include a introduction to the topic, but for now I am working under the assumption that you are at least vaguely familiar with the subject.

Two of the most famous algorithms for finding a minimum spanning tree are [Kruskal's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) and [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

***Explanation of the Algorithms to go here***

Now the question is "Which one is golfier"?

In order to figure this out are going to implement each of these two algorithms in as many languages as possible.  Each algorithm will have its own thread where it can be implemented in as many languages as possible.  Each thread will act as a team scoring points for the algorithm in question.  For each language a point will be given to the team with the shorter implementation in that language.

For example if the submissions look like this:

#### Kruskal

- Python, 136 bytes
- Bash, 215 bytes
- Brain-Flak, 3144 bytes

#### Prim

- Python, 152 bytes
- Bash, 211 bytes
- Perl, 98 bytes

Kruskal would score 2 points, one for having the shortest Python answer and one for the shortest Brain-Flak answer, and Prim would score 2 points one for having the shortest Bash answer and one for having the shortest Perl answer.

At the end of the week two winners will be declared, these will be the two persons that scored the most points for each team.  Additionally a winning team will be announced.  You can compete for both teams.

### Specifications

You will create a program or function that takes a graph in any reasonable form, implements one of the two algorithms and outputs the minimum spanning tree in any format that uniquely represents the spanning tree.

### Sandbox

- How can I make this clearer?
- What is confusing?
- Would this be fun?

Comment: I/O formats could make a significant difference.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't care about IO any form is fine

Comment: Implementing a given algorithm is tricky to define. To what extent can the method deviate from the algorithm?

Comment: @xnor Each of the two algorithms build the trees in a deterministic order.  In order for it to match the given algorithm it must add the edges in the same order.  I will add this to the question.

Comment: @WheatWizard That's a good idea, and I think it can be made into an observable requirement by requiring the algorithm output the correctly-ordered list of edges in the tree. Otherwise, I don't think the internal adding order is necessarily well-defined -- consider for example a functional-language recursive implementation.

Comment: This is basically just two different challenges which happen to be connected. I'd recommend posting it as two challenges, and then adding a snippet to compare the two challenges to see which problem is terser in the most languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Painter's Partition Problem

## Description

You have to paint N boards of length {A0, A1, A2, A3 … AN-1}. There are K painters available and each painter takes unit time to paint 1 unit of board. You have to get this job done as soon as possible under the constraints that any painter will only paint contiguous sections of board.

## Rules

- 2 painters cannot share a board to paint. That is to say, a board
  cannot be painted partially by one painter, and partially by another.
- A painter will only paint contiguous boards. Which means a
  configuration where painter 1 paints board 1 and 3 but not 2 is
  invalid.
- N boards have length given in integers.

---

#### Input

**K** : Number of painters

**L** : A List which will represent length of each board

#### Output

Return minimum time to paint all boards

#### Sample Input/Output

K      = 2

L      = [1, 10]

Output = 10

Comment: not sure why painters would only paint contiguous boards. But, without that the problem sounds like knapsack.

Comment: What is the point of T?

Comment: @JanDvorak Contiguous boards is creating a possibility of a solution other than DP (which is also more optimal).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually yes, I should remove it, I'll just make the time cost 1 unit.

Answer (score 0):

### find the set of Sets in a subset of Set.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

the Set game is a one-player card game using a deck of 81 cards. Derivatives - primarily those that remove most of the cards - exist. We shall be using one of such derivatives today.

a card in the deck is defined by four properties of the symbol(s) depicted on it. Each of these has one of three values:

- Count (1, 2 or 3); in this version, the count is always 1.
- Color: `r`ed, `g`reen or `b`lue.
- Fill: `h`ollow, `s`triped or `f`illed.
- shape: a `s`quare, a `t`riangle, or a `c`ircle.

A card shall be represented as a using those properties: `rhs` is a red hollow square, while `gsc` is a green solid circle.

a Set of cards is a triplet of cards such that for each property, the value of that property is either the same for all three cards or different for each of the three cards. For example:

- `rhs`, `gst` and `bfc` form a Set. Each property value is different.
- `rss`, `gss` and `bss` form a Set. They are solid squares of different colors.
- `bsc`, `bhs` and `bft` form a Set. The colors are the same, the fills are different, and the shapes are different.
- `gst`, `bst` and `bst` do not form a set, because there are two blue cards.
- `rss`, `bss` and `rst` do not form a set, because there are two red cards as well as two squares.
- `gft`, `gft` and `gft` do not form a set, because it's not a triplet of cards. It's the same card listed three times.

---

Your input shall be a set of 9 (distinct) cards from the deck. You may optionally accept a flat string or list of 27 symbols without any separator instead of a list of 9 strings or lists. You may also accept the number of Sets that can be found within this set as a part of your input. You may assume there's at least one Set in your input.

Your output shall be a set of all Sets that can be found among the cards given to you. You may output the Sets in any order, but each Set must only be output once. You may output the cards in each Set in any order as well. You may flatten the output at any level.

---

How many test cases should I generate? What format is the best? I could provide a test case generator in Ruby, if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

In our language, we use **language of S** for basic encryption for avoid something from children if we do not wish that children know about what we are talking about.

So here is how it works.
Lets take **"Hello there"** for example. So its encryption using **language of S** is **Hesmello Thesmere**

**Step to understand**

> **Step 1:** take string, in our example its "Hello There"
>   **Step 2:** add **S** and **M** after first character's vowel and add vowel of that first character after **M**.
>   You no need to repeate this for other characters of that word. So in our example, we add **SM** for **he** so no need to do that for remain **llo**.

So as per our example for "Hello There" is He**sme**llo the**sme**re

**What you have to do**
1. User add input (or pre defined string in variable) and its output should be as per Output String below

**Input :** Hello World
**Output:** Hesmello Wosmorld

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest number of bytes wins!

Consider these as vowels:**A, E, I, O, U, Y**

Comment: This isn't encryption. It's obfuscation.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This would probably make for an interesting challenge, but I would suggest removing the "pre-defined string in variable" option: our standard ways of taking input are STDIN or an argument to a function. Also, what characters can be part of a word? A-Z and a-z only?

Answer (score 0):

## Find a basis for each eigenspace!

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79545/jordan-decomposition)

The challenge is just as it seems; you are to find a basis for each eigenspace of a matrix. If you have taken Linear Algebra 1, you'll understand what this means, but this is an attempted full explanation of eigenvalues, eigenvectors, eigenspaces, what a basis is, and how to obtain all of these.

This is the challenge; the explanations are below so you can skip them if you already know how to do this.

## Input

The input will be a single matrix given in any reasonable format according to PPCG conventions.

## Output

The output will be an array of bases. There will be one basis for each eigenspace. You can choose whether or not to repeat eigenvalues with an arithmetic multiplicity of more than 1. This can be output in any reasonable format, probably a 3D array.

## Vectors

In Computer Science terms, a vector is an array of values. For the purposes of this, we are assuming that all of these values are in `Q`; that is, they are all rational numbers. [Wikipedia: Vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)

## Matrices

In Computer Science terms, a matrix is a 2D array of values. For the purposes of this, we are assuming that all of these values are in `Q`; that is, they are all rational numbers. [Wikipedia: Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))

## Terminology

Let `A` be an `m x n` matrix (with `m` rows and `n` columns) and let `x` be a size-`k` vector. Then, `Aij` is the element in the `i`-th row in the `j`-th column of `A` with `0 < i <= m` and `0 < j <= n` (they are 1-indexed). Also, `xi` is the `i`-th element of the vector `x` with `0 < i <= k`.

## The Zero Vector and the Zero Matrix

The zero vector is the vector containing all zeros. Similarly, the zero matrix is the matrix containing all zeros. It is important to note that the size still needs to be considered.

## Scalar Multiplication

Scalar multiplication by a value `s` (again we are assuming it is rational) is quite easy to understand; simply multiply each element by `s`. Thus, we say that `x` is a scalar multiple of `y` if and only if `x = sy`. Note that the zero-vector is a scalar multiple of any vector but all non-zero vectors are not scalar multiples of the zero vector.

## Matrix-Vector Multiplication [(MathInsight)](http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication)

Let `A` be an `m x n` matrix (with `m` rows and `n` columns) and let `x` be a size-`n` vector. Then, `Ax = y` where `y` is a size-`m` vector defined as such:

```
yi = Ai1*x1 + Ai2*x2 + ... + Ain*xn
```

That is, the `i`-th element in the result is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the `i`-th row of `A` and `x`.

## [Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

Let `λ != 0` be any real number, `A` be an `m x n` matrix, and `x != 0` be a size-`n` vector (not the number `0`, but the `0`-vector, which contains all zeros). Then, if `Ax = λx`, we say that `x` is an eigenvector of `A` corresponding to `λ`, and similarly, we say that `λ` is an eigenvalue of `A` corresponding to `x`.

## Determining Eigenvectors

It's easy to determine if `x` is an eigenvector of `A`. Simply check if `Ax` is a scalar multiple of `x`, which also gives us the corresponding eigenvalue `λ`. However, it is harder to find eigenvectors than to check it a vector is one.

## Finding Eigenvalues

Conversely, it's easier to find the eigenvalues but harder to check if a value is one, which is fortunate for this challenge. Firstly, we must look at determinants.

## Determinants

The determinant of a `2 x 2` matrix `[[a, b], [c, d]]` is `ad - bc`. This is a specific definition of the determinant, so in order to explain the recursive definition of a determinant, I will say that the determinant of a `1 x 1` matrix is that value. Note that only square matrices have a determinant.

### The recursive definition of a [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)

In order to give the recursive definition of a determinant, I first need to explain what `A(i,j)` means. `A(i,j)` is the matrix formed by removing the `i`-th row and the `j`-th column from `A`; thus, if `A` is an `n x n` matrix, `A(i,j)` is an `n-1 x n-1` matrix. Thus, we recursively define the determinant of an `n x n` matrix `A`, which we call `det A`, as `sum x=1->n (-1)^(x+1)*(det A(1,n))`. In other words, we go down the left-most column and take the values obtained from multiplying this value with the matrix formed by taking out the row and column it is in, and then alternate adding and subtracting those values. See the Wikipedia link for more information. This definition is recursive.

Also note that we do not have to expand on the left-most column, we can also expand on any column or any row.

So, how do determinants help us?

Well, I'm not going to prove it, but if we have `C(λ) = 0`, then `λ` is an eigenvalue of `A`. `C` is the characteristic polynomial function, which is gives the determinant of `A - λI`, where `λI` is scalar-multiplication between scalar `λ` and the Identity Matrix `I`, which has all `1`s on its main diagonal and `0`s everywhere else.

So, given an eigenvalue `λ`, we can find the [RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of `A - λI`. Let this matrix be `M`. Then, the eigenspace of `λ` corresponding to `A` is the set of all vectors `x` such that `Mx` is the zero-vector.

We have finally arrived at the task. Your task is to output, for each eigenvalue, a basis of the corresponding eigenspace.

## Linear Combination

A linear combinations of vectors `x1, x2, ..., xn` with scalars `s1, s2, ..., sn` is `s1x1 + ... + snxn`. When adding vectors, you add each individual element.

## Spanning Set

`S` is a spanning set of `B` if and only if every vector in `B` can be written as a linear combination of `S` with any real numbers as scalars.

## Linearly Independent Set

`L` is a linearly independent set if and only if no vector is a linear combination of the other vectors (thus `L` cannot contain the zero-vector), and it is linearly dependent otherwise.

## Basis: a linearly independent spanning set

A basis is simply a spanning set that's linearly independent. All possible bases will have the same number of vectors (proof omitted).

## The Challenge

Now that you hopefully understood my explanations, we arrive at the following challenge:

Given an `n x n` matrix with `0 < n <= 20`, for each eigenvalue (there will be at most `n` distinct ones), output a basis for the eigenspace of the eigenvalue. You can choose whether or not to output duplicates. You can choose the format for input and output within reasonable conditions. My recommendation is a 2D array for input and a 3D array for output. The input matrix is guaranteed to have only real eigenvalues, and is guaranteed to be square.

## I will add test cases if this challenge is posted because test cases are quite hard to create for this challenge!

## Fun Fact: "eigen" means "special" in German!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

Answer (score 0):

## Monitor your ARP table

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The Address Resolution Protocol is used to associate IP addresses on the local network with hardware addresses (aka MAC addresses). In its most basic form, ARP can be very insecure in the sense that your computer will believe anyone on the local network that says "Hey, this IP and this MAC go together!". This can be used [maliciously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing), so we want to keep an eye on our ARP caches.

Your task is to create a program that monitors your ARP cache and alerts you when changes have been made.

**Task**

Write a program that does the following:

- On initial execution, reads in the operating system's ARP table.
- With a frequency between once per second and once per ten seconds (inclusive), checks the operating system's ARP table for changes and prints something, as described immediately below:

-- If there is no change, print this exact string (with one or two trailing new lines):

`No Change`

-- If a new entry has appeared in the cache, print the string (with one or two trailing new lines):

`New Entry: <IP ADDRESS> --> <MAC ADDRESS>`

where `<IP ADDRESS>` is the IP address of the new entry (formatted as described below) and `<MAC ADDRESS>` is the MAC of the new entry (formatted as described below).

-- If any entry has changed to a new MAC (meaning an IP address is now being associated with a different MAC address) print the string (with one or two trailing new lines):

`!!! Possible Malicious Change: <IP ADDRESS> --> <NEW MAC ADDRESS> from <OLD MAC ADDRESS>`

where `<IP ADDRESS>` is the IP whose entry has changed (formatted as below), `<NEW MAC ADDRESS>` is the new MAC (formatted as below), and `<OLD MAC ADDRESS>` is the old MAC (formatted as below)

-- If any entry has changed to a to `<incomplete>` (meaning an IP address is now being associated with nothing) print the string (with one or two trailing new lines):

`Entry incomplete: <IP ADDRESS> --> <incomplete> from <OLD MAC ADDRESS>`

where `<incomplete>` is a literal.

--- If an entry is now missing, print the string (with one or two trailing new lines):

`Entry for <IP ADDRESS> (<MAC ADDRESS>) is gone.`

- The program repeats until terminated.

**Formatting**

IP addresses have 4 octets that are dot separated. They may be formatted in either of the following fashions:

- in hex: e.g. `02.22.DC.FD`, leading zeros MUST be included, alphabetical digits may be capital or lowercase, as long as cases are not mixed within a single IP address.
- in decimal: e.g. `22.54.198.9`, leading zeros MUST NOT be included.

MAC addresses have 6 octets that are colon separated and must be formatted in the following fashion:

- in hex: e.g. `0F:CD:12:44:22:F1`, leading zeros must be included, alphabetical digits may be capital or lowercase, as long as cases are not mixed within a single IP address.

A MAC address can also be a string literal to the effect of "`incomplete`" or "`unknown`" if that is what is in your arp cache. If it is, this should be used literally instead of an actual MAC address.

**Operating System Differences**

The three major operating systems (Mac, Linux, Windows) all use ARP and I'm fairly certain that all other modern OS's do as well. Your program need only run on a SINGLE operating system, to be specified in your submission header by its main type (e.g. `Linux`) and in your submission body by a fuller identifier (e.g. `Centos 6.5`). We will view each OS as it's own competition.

**Testing things**

The following commands will change your ARP table on Linux (and Mac?).

Add a (static) entry or overwrite an existing entry: `arp -s <IP> <MAC>`, e.g. `arp -s 2.2.2.2 ab:cd:ef:12:34:56`

Delete an entry: `arp -d <IP>`, e.g. `arp -d 2.2.2.2`

Flush all: `ip neighbor flush all`

Comment: Is there an easier way to test submissions than building a local network with multiple devices?

Comment: @Laikoni yes (at least on linux), static entries can be added to the table using `arp -s`. I'm sure there is something similar on other OS's.

Comment: That's good to know. You could add a test script which triggers the different outputs to make the challenge a bit more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

## Find all the triples!

Your task is, given a number `n`, find all the Pythagorean triples containing that number, and output a list of the terms in each Pythagorean triple which is not `n`, without repeats and in ascending order.

For example, given `8` as an input, there are two Pythagorean triples which contain `8`:

```
6 8 10
8 15 17
```

The terms in each Pythagorean triple (without `8`) are:

```
6 10 15 17
```

Because this set doesn't have repeats and is in ascending order, we can output just that.

You must write a program or function that takes one input, and your output can either be your language's representation of a list, or a string with any delimiter. So these outputs for `8` are all valid:

```
[6 10 15 17]    (Clojure list)
[6, 10, 15, 17] (Python list)
6 10 15 17      (uses space delimiter)
6#10#15#17      (uses "#" delimiter)
```

### Rules and Specs:

- You are guaranteed that the input is a positive integer.
- Your program must return the correct output for 3600 in 60 seconds. This is the same amount of time as TIO timing out. The output for 3600 should be:

  ```
  147 380 425 660 810 1008 1050 1204 1342 1500 1755 1920 2160 2240 2415 2700 2880 2886 3190 3250 3456 3570 3603 3620 3625 3660 3690 3750 3780 3796 3842 3900 4005 4080 4125 4240 4335 4352 4500 4559 4614 4800 4810 4850 5049 5070 5220 5460 5475 5648 5809 5980 6000 6201 6270 6540 6750 6980 7068 7230 7595 7650 7700 7932 8265 8405 8500 8640 9015 9360 9676 9805 10324 10445 10500 10962 11100 11538 11730 12270 12710 13210 13260 13740 14175 14625 14784 15216 16000 16400 16683 17067 17820 18180 19838 20090 20162 20410 21450 21750 22356 22644 23865 24135 25795 26045 26880 27120 29892 30108 32300 32500 33654 33846 35910 36090 39919 40081 40420 40580 43125 43275 44928 45072 50561 50689 53940 54060 59946 60054 64750 64850 67452 67548 71955 72045 80960 81040 89964 90036 101218 101282 107970 108030 119973 120027 129575 129625 134976 135024 161980 162020 179982 180018 202484 202516 215985 216015 269988 270012 323990 324010 359991 360009 404992 405008 539994 540006 647995 648005 809996 810004 1079997 1080003 1619998 1620002 3239999 3240001
  ```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: 1) What should be returned for numbers which don't show up in any Pythagorean triple? 2) I'm not sure the sorting adds anything to the challenge. 3) You didn't state a winning criterion yet.

Comment: @Laikoni 1) All numbers (except for 1 and 2) should have Pythagorean triples. 2) I can get rid of it, if you want. 3) Fixed.

Comment: What about 0? With the current spec I think it should be in every output.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a 'Logical' interpreter

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

'Logical' is an esoteric language I am working on.

It involves 4 logic gates, AND(&), OR(|), NOT(!) and XOR(^).

Since only having 4 logic gates, the IO is only true or false (We are not discussing Qubits here :P)

It will have some lines in the format `[input 1] [(not included in not gates) input 2] [output] [gate]`, showing which node is connected to which logic gate. For example, `1 2 3 &` would mean node 1 and 2 are connected to an AND gate, and the output goes to node 3.

During the interpretation, it should get the status of the input nodes(nodes which are only connected to an input of a logic gate) as an array of tuples. For example, `[[1,true][2,true]]` is a valid input for the program `1 2 3 &`.

Then the interpreter should output the result of the output nodes(nodes which are only connected to an output of a logic gate), also as an array of tuples. For example, `[[3,true]]` is the output for `1 2 3` when given the input `[[1,true],[2,true]]`.

## Examples

[Too long, pastebin coming soon]

## Rules

- No logic gates will be given one or more input nodes as same as their output nodes.
- A blank program is invalid, thus will not be given.

### OP's note

> I have clearly made this esolang for fun, but I hope it will be on some challenges, or make people understand more on logic gates.

Comment: The language is missing quite some specification. You give syntax for a program consisting of one gate, but how do programs with multiple gates look?

Comment: `1 2 3 & 3 2 !` doesn't violate the constraint "*No logic gates will be given one or more input nodes as same as their output nodes*" but it does give an unstable circuit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is that a flip-flop?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk, no. A flip-flop settles into a stable state, whereas an AND whose output feeds via a NOT into one of its inputs can only settle into a stable state when the other input is 0.

Answer (score 0):

### <s>All your base are belong to us</s> 6 * 9 = 42

When Douglas Adams wrote THHGTTG, he just made up a formula for the answer to Life, the Universe and Everything. And then some spoilsport pointed out that it was a valid formula... when interpreted in base 13.

Given an input formula, please output as many bases as you can find where the formula is valid.

You must at a minimum support base 10 to base 16 inclusive, but you are strongly recommended to support base 2 to at least base 36.

You must at a minimum support the `()*+=` operators, but you are strongly recommended to support `-` and `/`, and either `**` or `^` for exponentiation. Note that the division will always be exact in valid bases, but may not be exact in invalid bases, so for `11/2=8` you should only output `15`.

Examples

```
11/2=8
15

10+10=10*10
2

6*9=42
13

11**11=2101
3
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: As Many Bases as possible seems, annoying...

Comment: "You must at minimum do this, but you are strongly recommended to also do that" doesn't sound like a great formula for challenges... I'd try to choose a fixed set of requirements and stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

### Nearly-match a string

Our near miss algorithm is too slow. The boss is blaming the Levenshtein distance builtin for being overkill for our purpose as we're only interested in a distance of 1. Please code something leaner.

Input: Two different strings, in any reasonable format. At least 36 different characters should be supported.

Output: A truthy/falsy value which distinguishes between strings with a Levenshtein distance of 1 or more than 1.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins! Builtins that calculate the Levenshtein distance are not allowed.

Comment: What's the rationale for choosing 36 in "at least 36 different characters"?

Comment: `[a-z0-9]`, perhaps?

Comment: The back story actively contradicts the scoring criterion. Golfed answers are likely to be much slower than the builtin.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Surely that depends on the language. I suspect a C answer for the specific challenge would outspeed any generic library.

Answer (score 0):

## Shh... Can you Split a Secret? [cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In *Applied Cryptography* by Bruce Schnieier (which I have been reading quite a lot recently), a protocol for splitting secrets is discussed. Here is a brief description:

> 1. Trent generates a random string, *R*, the same length as the message, *M*.
> 2. Trent XORS *M* with *R* to make *S*.
> 3. He gives *R* to Alice and *S* to Bob.

---

Your task is to, given an input, split the input into the two outputs. One output should contain the random string; the other should contain the original input XOR'd with the random string. Input and output may be to/from files or to/from STDIN/STDOUT. Outputting to STDERR is also allowed.
There are a few restrictions, however:

1. Your program must take 3 inputs, and output the random string and the original string XOR'd with that random string into the other.
2. Your program must be cryptographically secure. All random number generators must be cryptographically secure. For example, `/dev/random` is fine, but the Mersenne Twister (usually `randint(number,number)` is *not*. Any random number generator must be *explicitly* cryptographically secure.

   - If you want to know anything more about what "cryptographically secure" means, check [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-number-generator-to-be-cryptographically-secure).
3. Standard rules and loopholes apply.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes will win.
May the best coder prosper...

Comment: Is there a reason you are requiring input/output to be file-based?  That removes a lot of languages out of the challenge.

Comment: @NathanMerrill What should I change?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I did kind of have file I/O in mind...

Comment: Simply take in a single string as input (M), and have it output two strings (R and S).  Writing/reading from a file is trivial in most languages, but in others its literally impossible.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm not very good at cryptography, so I may be wrong here, but I think that "cryptographically secure" is a bit too broad.  Explaining to use `/dev/random` is great, but what other steps need to be taken to ensure it's cryptographically secure?

Comment: @NathanMerrill See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

Answer (score 0):

## Secret Santa

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

**Goal:** Given a list of names with public keys, assign each person a name, encrypt it with their public key and print the list of gifters with their encoded giftees.

### Introduction

My family wanted to get a head start on Secret Santa (so they can shop sales though out the year). The problem was "how do we do this remotely?" Pubic key encryption, of course! My family is not very tech-savvy (or math-savvy). So after a several hours of phone calls, I was able to get everyone to generate public+private keys ([by hand](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html)) and chat them to the group. Now I need to message back a gifter/giftee list.

### Specification

- **Input**

  - Flexible
  - A list of `First Name, Last Name, Piece One of Key, Piece Two of Key` tuples
  - So `[ John, Smith, 351, 174 ]` is an example tuple
  - `n` would be `351`
  - `e` would be `174`
  - Each name will be nonempty, capital and lowercase letters
  - Initials will be unique
- **Algorithm**

  - For each tuple (i.e. `gifter`)
  - Randomly assign a `giftee` such that `giftee != gifter`
  - [NOTE] Each `giftee` should be assigned to exactly one `gifter`
  - Get the `giftee`'s first initial and last initial
  - `A or a = 1`, `B or b = 2`, ..., `Z or z = 26`
  - Encrypt each initial
- [**Encryption**](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html)

  - The encryption of a number `x` is `x^e % n`
- **Output**

  - Flexible
  - A list of `gifters` (first and last name) with the encrypted first and last initial of their `giftee`
- **Score**

  - Shortest code in bytes wins

### Test Cases

```
Input                         Middle Step                   Output
-----                         -----------                   ------
[Sherlock Holmes,1363,3]      Irene Adler => IA             [Sherlock Holmes,729,1]       
[John Watson,1763,11]         Mycroft Holmes => MH          [John Watson,281,935]         
[Mary Watson,1927,3]          John Watson => JW             [Mary Watson,1000,605]        
[Mycroft Holmes,1271,7]       Peter Jones => PJ             [Mycroft Holmes,256,1043]     
[Irene Adler,1073,5]          Mary Watson => MW             [Irene Adler,35,489]          
[Peter Jones,1073,5]          Sherlock Holmes => SH         [Peter Jones,688,578]
```

Comment: "*Assign a giftee such that giftee != gifter*" seems to be lacking a constraint that each person should be giftee of exactly one gifter.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good catch! I clarified that "*Each giftee should be assigned to exactly one gifter*"

Answer (score 0):

## Many Happy Returns!

I'm not sure whether to make this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

---

Write a function that when it returns, it returns an extra frame up the stack.  In other words, functions usually return directly to their callers; however, here the function should return directly to its caller's caller.  To illustrate, consider this [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int b(void) {
    int rc = 3;
    printf("%s(): returning from b()\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return rc;
}

int a(void) {
    int rc;
    rc = b();
    printf("%s(): returned from b()=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, rc);
    return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    int rc;
    rc = a();
    printf("%s(): returned from a()=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, rc);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this program is:

```c
b(): returning from b()
a(): returned from b()=3
main(): returned from a()=2
```

An entry to this challenge would return from the innermost function `c()` in a special way such that the output is:

```c
b(): returning from b()
main(): returned from a()=3
```

Note that the flow of execution goes directly from the return of `b()` back to the next line after where `main()` called `a()`.  The `returned from b()` message is not output as this code never executes.  It is not sufficient just to put this message in a conditional.

#### Rules

Assuming a template similar to this sample - i.e. `main()` calls `a()` calls `b()`:

- Entries are scored by the size of function `b()` in bytes - smallest wins.
- Functions `main()` and `a()` must be provided, but are not included in the score
- There must be no special logic in `main()` and `a()` that help.  If the call to `b()` were replaced with a call to `b1()` (a normal function that returns normally), with no other modifications, then the `returned from b()` message would be observed.
- You may assume that the return types of `a()` and `b()` are the same

---

I am aware that there are languages which make this very easy, but it is significantly more challenging (or maybe impossible) in other languages.  I don't want to explicitly ban any languages, but I am most interested in the answers where the solution is non-trivial.

Comment: Your example is much longer and verbose than it needs to be, to the point that I think it's harder to follow than a minimal example would be.

Comment: @Sparr I've shortened the example somewhat

Comment: What can be assumed about `a()`, particularly in terms of how many elements and of what type it will allocate on the stack?

Answer (score 0):

## MCDI: Make and Change Directory into

**Input:** A string consisting of only alphanumeric characters, whose length does not exceed 255. It is given as string input, through STDIN on a single line, through ARGV, etc.

**Effect:** If a directory with the given name does not exist in the current directory, create it. Then, change the current directory to that directory. You can assume that no file with the given name exists.

Here is an example Batch script that does this (ungolfed, of course):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST %1 MKDIR %1
CD %1
```

Comment: if it's possible but not normal to create directory names containing "/" or "\" in your environment, what should the script do when it encounters those?

Comment: @Sparr *A string consisting of only alphanumeric characters*

Comment: @Sparr Yeah, I didn't want to get into the nitty-gritty of file system's allowed characters (especially window's), so I restricted the domain to alphanumeric characters (as seen by the first sentence)

Comment: Can we assume that there is no file with the same name?

Comment: Also, what about full programs? I don't know how this works on Windows, but in Linux, you can only change the directory for the program itself. Once it finishes, you'll be back where you started.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, hm. I suppose the batch script only works like that because it's windows. Perhaps I should add some sort of requirement, like, copy the original file to the location. Thoughts?

Comment: @Dennis: that's not *quite* true. "/bin/cd" is a bit of a running joke in the esolangs community, because it's a fun absurd concept; it *is* possible to write, but it isn't possible to write in any sort of sane way. (When I wrote it myself, I had it attach a debugger to the parent process to change the current directory inside that process directly.) Without using debugger tricks, the program would need to run inside the parent process directly, which would basically limit the choice of language to sourced shellscripts (including the batch in the OP; that's a sourced language).

Comment: Point taken, but I doubt the OP was expecting us to write something like that.

Answer (score 0):

## Meta Code Golf [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Late new year resolution: I'm finally cleaning up all my input and output files I used for code golf previously. Only problem is, I don't know which input and output files go to which code golf question on this site.

All problems used in this question should be posted on or before 31st December 2016 23:59:59 (GMT).

Input format:

The input would consist of an input and a correct output for the code golf question.

Each file can be accepted as an input file with a hardcoded filename, in the standard input, or as a function argument. The output can be a function return value, written to a file, or to standard output.

In the case both files are in standard input, you are allowed to define any arbitrary separator as long as it is consistent for all input files, and the separator is less than 16 bytes long.

You may assume that the separator is neither in the input file or in the output files. (All possible input files/output files with the separator in it are not used for scoring purposes.)

Output format:

Your code is required to output the ID of the question. Your code is allowed to have other non-numerical output.

For example, for this question:

```
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/rearrangement-inequality
```

You can output any one of the following:

```
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/rearrangement-inequality
64449
The question ID is 64449.
Just look at question 64449. You can find the question there.
```

### Sandbox Meta: Scoring definitions

For each input-output pair, it may correspond to multiple questions. In that case, you may choose to output multiple answers, or only one answer. An input-output pair is considered to be *correctly classified* if it has at least one correct answer, and all provided answers are correct.

A question is considered *correctly classified* only if all input-output pairs corresponding to the question are *correctly classified* and the question ID is in the output for at least one of the input-output pairs corresponding to the question.

### Sandbox Meta: Alternative definition

A question is considered *correctly classified* only if all input-output pairs with the question ID in the output are actual input-output pairs to the question, and all input-output pairs which do not correspond to the question do not have the question ID in the output.

Your score is the length of your code divided by the square of the number of *correctly classified* questions.

In the case the total number of questions you *correctly classify* is zero, you score positive infinity. Why am I even saying this? Of course it should work on at least one question.

Also, please claim the questions that your program *correctly classified*.

In the case that there are many ways the input and output for the question can be formatted, you are allowed to choose any one of them in the question, which is clearly allowed before 31st December 2016 23:59:59 GMT. You are allowed to choose different input/output formats for different questions.

It is guaranteed that none of the input-output pairs have infinite input or output.
It is guaranteed that none of the input-output pairs have

### I have some concerns:

As I may not have online access all the time, your code should not rely on looking at StackExchange to find the questions.

### Finally:

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), and the winner will be the person with the lowest score, in case of a tie, it would be tiebroken by submission time.

### Sandbox Meta:

Lots of these questions might be difficult to encode the input, for example questions where the input is to a function.

Comment: What exactly is the input? A single test case, and the program should output a question for which the test case would pass?

Comment: @PeterTaylor
The input consists of an input file, and a correct output for that question.
The output would be the ID of the question. (Sorry if it wasn't clear.)

Answer (score 0):

## Simplify Brainf**k

We'll call a language *BF equivalent* if it emits a context-free substitution mapping to and from BF. For example, consider the hypothetical language *SimpleBrain* which is identical to BF except that it does not include `+` or `>`, but instead has `}`. It emits the following mapping to BF:

```
}: +>
<: <
-: -
.: .
,: ,
[: [
]: ]
```

And the following mapping from BF:

```
+: }<
>: -}
<: <
-: -
.: .
,: ,
[: [
]: ]
```

## Challenge

Design a BF equivalent language. The language with the fewest commands wins (*SimpleBrain*, for example, has 7). In the event of a tie (which is likely) the language with the shortest representation with the mapping you provide of the following BF program wins:

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>
++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.
+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

## Sandbox Notes

There have been many efforts to "simplify" BF, but most of them shift complexity from the language to the interpreter. I've tried to formulate the rules in such a way that this cannot happen.

Are there interesting solutions to this challenge? I can only think of a few. I'd love to seem some creative answers to this problem. I am also looking for ways to better define *context-free substitution mapping* as what I have in mind clearly excludes trivial reductions like [Braincrash](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braincrash) because there is not a context-free mapping from Braincrash to BF, but I don't know if that's totally clear from the wording. By context-free substitution mapping, I mean substitution rules of the form:

```
a := b_1 b_2 ... b_n
```

where `a` is a single command in the source language and the RHS is any finite number of commands in the language we're mapping to (the LHS consists of a single symbol which is why I described it as context-free).

I also question whether this is exactly a programming puzzle per say. I am open to reformulating the challenge to make it better suited for the site if there is opposition.

Comment: [esolangs](https://esolangs.org/) seems to be down but if memory serves, there are 2-command or 1-command equivalents/analogs (Unary *might* count but I can't reference how it works) which already exist. Also I *think* an implication of Turing completeness implies that you can create a mapping to commands in another Turing complete language but I have not taken enough CS theory to back up that intuition.

Comment: Yeah, Braincrash is the first 2-command example that comes to mind. There are also trivial equivalents that claim to reduce BF to two characters by using what amounts to a different encoding. But, as far as I can tell there isn't a mapping like the one I am trying to describe from any of these languages to BF (thus, they would not qualify).  If you can find an example do let me know :)

Comment: Also, I agree with your intuition that there exist mappings between any two turing-complete languages, though I think they are usually not context-free.

Comment: One more comment: context-free is probably not the right word to use. I mean that the substitution rules are in the form A -> B_1B_2...B_n where LHS is a single command and RHS is any finite number of commands.

Comment: This is a [tag:code-challenge] with [tag:metagolf] as the tiebreak, so I'd say it's reasonable here. Also, it's going in a different direction from the typical BF minimizations on Esolang (although I've seen similar minimizations for other languages, like Underload); I like the requirement for the language to be compilable to and from BF by replacing each single character with a specific string, which puts hard limits on what sorts of cheating are allowed. I'd recommend that the equivalence be in terms of I/O behaviour, not values stored on the tape (so that the tape format can be changed).

Comment: I like this challenge, but the simplest would only need two symbols a la Ook.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a generated MIDI sound better

Being a crazy man, I sometimes listen to music made to midi trough a filter that makes it MIDI. It is a great experience, but I need to work a lot on it, because MIDI has a lot of instruments, and not every one sound good with every track

### Challenge

Write a program that that finds which instrument represents the song the best

- [Filter that is used](http://www.ofoct.com/audio-converter/convert-wav-or-mp3-ogg-aac-wma-to-midi.html)
- [Soundfont that is used](http://timtechsoftware.com/ad.html?keyword=sf2%20format?file_name=the%20General%20MIDI%20Soundfont?file_url=uploads/GeneralUser_GS_SoftSynth_v144.sf2)

### Input

A single .mid file

### Output

A number representing MIDI instrument

### Scoring

Score=Similarity/length by characters

Similarity is defined by executing Fourier transform and finding the percent of similarity between original and output sounds

### Meta

Is this any good? and is scoring not exploitable?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details on what task exactly is needed to perform. Also on how many test cases is the similarity mentioned in the scoring computed? Do you already have a program to measure similarity?

Comment: @Laikoni It's the part I'm working on now, so it may change a lot. I don't already have a program to measure similarity, but looks like it's preety easily done in Audacity. For test cases, i have some, but i don't have enough rep to add them.

Comment: @ais523 I'm sure that it's difficult, it would already been done by now :) . For anti-brute-force restriction, i can't find a way to solve this puzzle that wouldn't be brute-forcing, so maybe adding a speed requirement would help? Or something that would require effective brute-forcing.

Comment: [tag:restricted-complexity] is probably the best way to add a speed requirement here (if you restrict it to quadratic, that means that doubling the length of the music to analyse can increase the runtime by no more than a factor of 4). That would allow pretty much all legitimate solutions, but disallow pretty much all brute force solutions

Answer (score 0):

## Goodstein Sequences

From Wikipedia:

The Goodstein sequence G(m) of a number m is a sequence of natural numbers. The first element in the sequence G(m) is m itself. To get the second, G(m)(2), write m in hereditary base-2 notation, change all the 2s to 3s, and then subtract 1 from the result. In general, the (n + 1)-st term G(m)(n + 1) of the Goodstein sequence of m is as follows:

1. Take the hereditary base-n + 1 representation of G(m)(n).
2. Replace each occurrence of the base-n + 1 with n + 2.
3. Subtract one. (Note that the next term depends both on the previous term and on the index n.)
4. Continue until the result is zero, at which point the sequence terminates.

Example: The Goodstein sequence for 13 is:

1. 2^(2+1)+2^2+2^0 = 13
2. 3^(3+1)+3^3+3^0-1 = 3^(3+1)+3^3 = 108
3. 4^(4+1)+4^4-1 = 4^(4+1)+3*4^3+3*4^2+3*4^1+3*4^0 = 1279
4. 5^(5+1)+3*5^3+3*5^2+3*5^1+3*5^0-1 = 5^(5+1)+3*5^3+3*5^2+3*5^1+2*5^0 = 16092
5. 6^(6+1)+3*6^3+3*6^2+3*6^1+2*6^0-1 = 6^(6+1)+3*6^3+3*6^2+3*6^1+6^0 = 280711

And so on

## Your Task

Print the first 3 terms of the Goodstein sequence that starts on the input. If there are fewer than 3 terms, print out all the terms in the sequence (e.g. for input 1).

Example inputs and outputs:

> Input: 1, Output: 1, 0
>
> Input: 2, Output: 2, 2, 1
>
> Input: 3, Output: 3, 3, 3
>
> Input: 4, Output: 4, 26, 41

You may assume that the input will be a natural number from 1-200. Note that one of the challenges of this challenge is to support integers over 2^500.

## Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins! Answers from all languages are encouraged. The speed of the solution does not matter, as long as it eventually prints out the desired answer.

## Fun Fact

All Goodstein sequences eventually converge to 0.

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory, base-conversion

Comment: [Close enough to be considered a dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44453/194)

Answer (score 0):

## Darwin Fights

(code-challenge)

You are fighting a swarm of evolving enemies. Your goal is to outsmart them by turning evolution on its head.

The game consists of multiple *rounds*, starting with round 0. Every round `n` contains `5(n+1)` enemies, so it starts out with 5, then 10, and so on. Each enemy has a couple statistics:

1. Health -- the amount of health the enemy has left
2. Attack -- the damage that the enemy can do
3. Defense -- reduces damage done
4. Reproduction -- controls the rate (chance) of reproduction
5. Blur -- Makes the enemy seem weaker than it actually is.

The starting values for these numbers are taken from the previous round (details below), or if it is the first round, a mutated form of the enemy with health 1, attack 0, defense 0, reproduction 1, and blur 0. The player also has similar stats: health, attack, defense, and regeneration (how much health recovered per turn). You start off with 100 health, and the only condition on attack, defense, and regeneration is that their sum must be less than or equal to 10.

**Details of turn order**:

1. All the enemies attack you, you lose health according to the damage formula below.
2. You choose 3 enemies to attack or you nuke them (see below). It is advised to choose the 3 most powerful enemies to stop them from reproducing.
3. All surviving enemies have the chance to reproduce. If `r` is their reproduction coefficient, their chance of reproducing is `r/n` where `n` is the total number of enemies. Thus, the expected number of new enemies is the average value of all the enemies' `r`-values.
4. If there are no surviving enemies, the round is over. The next round starts and is populated with `5(n+1)` enemies. Your health is restored. The next round's enemies' stats are determined by a weighted average of all the dead enemies' stats of the current round. They are weighted by the number of steps they survived in that round. Thus, it is important to eliminate strong enemies early in the round.

**Damage**: If the attacker has attack `a` and defender has defense `d`, the amount of health lost by the defender is `a*(1-d/25)`. The minimum amount of damage is capped at `a/4`, so the value of `d` is essentially capped at `18.75` (it can be higher, but it wouldn't do any good).

**Input** You will get input in the following manner: a list of lists, each list containing the data for one enemy, in the order `[health, attack, defense, reproduction]`. Each of these values is reduced by a number uniformly chosen between `0` and `blur`. You will return the indices of the enemies you want to attack. If you return anything other than a list of 3 nonnegative integers (so e.g. an empty list), you choose to *nuke* the enemies.

**Nuke**: Nuking is just the ability to attack every enemy in a single turn. After nuking, you must wait 10 turns before being able to nuke again. Warning: since nuking attacks all enemies, it is common that a nuke will leave only strong enemies behind. Thus if there are survivors that reproduce, they will be the strongest. Use nukes carefully!

**Reproduction**: If an enemy is able to reproduce, it will choose a mate to mate with. The chance of being chosen as a mate is proportional to the attack power. It is possible the enemy's mate is itself (asexual), or that there is only one enemy left, in which case it is forced to reproduce asexually. The new enemy's traits is based on the average of the parents' traits, added to a mutation

**Mutations**: As soon as an organism is created, whether at the beginning of the round or from parents, its values are mutated. A normally distributed random number with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.3 is added to each one. A mutation will never cause the starting health or reproduction coefficient to go below 1, and will never cause the attack or defense to go below zero.

**Score**: Your score is the number of rounds you survive. Ties are broken by the amount of least health you had left at the end of any round before the last round. Scoring will be based off of taking your median run after running your code for a large number of times (to be determined, on the order of 100).

**Controller:** Currently written in python, available here: https://gist.github.com/prakol16/f0a306efd63a977a95c034b4b6e00ef1#file-darwin_main-py. To write your own class, extend the class Player and override the methods `__init__` and `get_attack`

```
class ExamplePlayer(Player):
def __init__(self):
    # Should add up to 10
    super().__init__(attack=3, defense=0, regeneration=7)

def get_attack(self, enemies, round_num, nuke_recharge):
    if self.get_health() < 50 and nuke_recharge == 0:
        return [0]  # Nuke it!
    return [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Linear Chemistry

Input is a string representing a skeletal formula of a molecule, in a format similar to `O=C-O-H`. However as a lot of formulas contain carbon and hydrogen atoms, it is customary to skip them from the description and just signal their presence by only displaying the used bonds. We will call these atoms implicit atoms, while the ones that are shown explicitly in the formula explicit atoms.

Your job is to calculate the number of different atoms a specific skeletal formula contains.

The input is a one line string containing the following tokens:

- `-`, `=`, `≡` symbolizing the bonds between the atoms
- Any uppercase character followed by a number of lowercased characters symbolizing an atom of some sort (e.g. `O`, `H`, `Br`, `Uub`, etc.)

You have to output the number of different atoms this molecule contains in any sensible format.

Notes:

- You can omit specifying the number of atoms if there is only one in the molecule
- You may or may not merge the number of implicit and explicit atoms of `C` and `H` molecules (e.g. you can treat them as separate types).
- You can output the atoms in any order

For example for the input string `-OH` valid output can be:

- `CH₃OH` (preferred output)
- `CH3OH`
- `CH4O`
- `H4O1C1`
- `{C:1,H:4,O:1}`

Invalid outputs:

- `CHHHOH` (you have to merge the same type of atoms into one)
- `CH2OH2` (you have to maintain the numbers for explicit and implicit `C` and `H` atoms properly if you didn't merge them)

You can use the following rules to parse the input:

- For every explicit atom present in the input there will be one atom in the output. E.g. `OOHOBrUub` is `O₃H₁Br₁Uub₁`
- Every bond token between two explicit atom tokens can be ignored. E.g. `O-O`, `OO` and `O=O` all mean the same thing: `O₂`
- Two bond tokens following each other, or a bond token at any end of the string means an implicit `C` molecule and some amount of `H` molecules. The amount of `H` molecules will be 4 minus the amount of dashes in the bond tokens (1 for `-`, 2 for `=` and 3 for `≡`). E.g. `O--O` means `O₂CH₂`, `O-=O` means `O₂CH` and `O==O`/`O-≡O` both mean `CO₂`.
- You can always assume that there will be no invalid inputs where the number of implicit hydrogen atoms would be negative (e.g. `≡=`, `≡≡`, or `=≡`)

Examples:

```
-: C₂H₆
≡: C₂H₂
--: C₃H₈
==: C₃H₄
O==O: CO₂
-OH: CH₃OH (or CH₄O)
--OH: C₂H₅OH (or C₂H₆O)
-=-: C₄H₈
≡-≡: C₄H₂
=O≡-≡O=: C₄O₂H₄
Br-O-C-=Uub: BrOCCUubH (or BrOC₂UubH)
```

This is code golf, so shortest submission wins.

Comment: 1. The last test case seems to be missing two hydrogens from the explicit carbon. 2. I think that the detailed explanation of how implicit atoms work needs to be earlier. Most of the spec assumes that you understand it, but it comes right at the end. 3. I find it rather confusing that sometimes the bonds are omitted completely in the explanations (e.g. in `OOHOBrUub`), and even more so that none of the test cases cover this.

Comment: 1. You don't need to add hydrogens for the explicit atoms, I probably have to add this. 2. I wasn't sure where to put it exactly, I could swap the output spec with the input parsing 3. They're okay by the spec, and there are some examples (`OH`), but you are right I might need to add some more

Answer (score 0):

## Let's play hide and seek.

The objective of this game is for the user to pick a spot on a grid (size given by user). For example, here is a 5x5 grid below.

```
--------------------------
| A1 |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    | A
--------------------------
|    |    |    |    | B5 |
|    |    |    |    |    | B
--------------------------
|    | ME |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    | C
--------------------------
|    | D2 |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    | D
--------------------------
|    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    | E
--------------------------
  1    2    3     4    5
```

Each tile is identified by its cross section of letters and numbers, A1, D2, and B5 are shown above.

The user picks a random tile to hide in. I picked C2.

Now, you must build a program that will guess tiles.

If you are in the tile, you will respond with `Y` meaning the computer won.

Otherwise, you will give the direction from the guessed tile (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). So if the computer guesses `D3`, you would input `NW`.

Let me show you an example of what the program should look like.

```
Grid?
5x5
```

Pick: E2

```
Guess: C3?
SW
Guess: D2?
S
Guess: E2?
Y
```

The scoring for this program: The program will be tested for three different scenarios using the grid sizes: 5x5, 10x10, 20x10

The program should be able to guess the correct square in the minimum number of guesses.

Then, lowest bytes wins.

Comment: With your four scenarios I can get it in an average of 1.75. This is also an incredibly poor scoring system.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Should I make it a requirement to get the correct answer in the minimum number of guesses (and specify for each case)... and then just lowest bytes wins?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thanks for posting in the sandbox! I like the premise of this challenge but as fəˈnɛtɪk has pointed out in the current form the scoring system is poorly defined. Also allowing larger board sizes might make for a harder challenge.

Comment: As a code challenge, this scoring system is incredibly bad because it will essentially allow you to pick and choose which answer will win. It would be better if you just made it a Code-golf challenge for code that will use the least moves on average to cover the entire board.

Answer (score 0):

## How far is this list from sorted?

**Input:** sequence of whitespace-separated base-10 integers (on stdin).

**Output:** minimal count (base-10 integer) of numbers which have to be moved to a different position in order to sort the list (to stdout).

#### Example

Input

> 0 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 7 8

becomes sorted by moving at least two numbers ‒ 3 and 9.

> 0 1 2 **3** 4 5 6 7 8 **9**

so the output would be `2`.

- For already sorted (including constant) or empty lists, the result is 0.
- Shortest entry wins.

Comment: Can the input be a string or literary a list of numbers?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/shortest-longest-increasing-subsequence-code), if I understand the task correctly.

Comment: @Zgarb No, that's something different. For sequence `1 7 2 2 4`, the result of the task you linked would be `2` (the longest _strictly increasing subsequence_). In my task, it's `1` (you have to move `7` to the end to make it sorted). I think my task would be a bit more difficult than the other one.

Comment: @kyrill, the result of the task Zgarb linked would be `3` because the longest strictly increasing subsequence is `1 2 4`. Relax the *strictly* and it's asking for the length of the list minus the answer to your proposed question. I agree with Zgarb that it's a dupe.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right, I didn't realize that. Duplicate it is.

Answer (score 0):

## Route the phone calls

The challenge is to take the 3 ascii cities with 3 zones and  (meta: in progress) and two phone numbers, you will return the cities with the phone lines that are used to connect the two calls replaced with a symbol of you choosing that is not used in the cities. (I will provide the cities at the end of this challenge post so you know).

## Rules and notes

Everything must be the same except the phone lines (they will be the letter L)

Standard rules

The cities will be top down

## Input

The cities shown as is without newlines (the cities will be connected together with phone lines :)

Two phone numbers (will be valid)in the format (xxxxxxxxxx)

## Output

The cities with the connected calls

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Meta

This is going to be a big project. I am not done writing the challenge for sure. I need cities and will start to make some but if anyone has cities or makes any I would be happy, a website with cities would also be pretty chill.

Any advice welcome

Also I am posting in sandbox as I have to get off the computer :P

Answer (score 0):

## Find the Least Conforming Word

## Given a list of words, find which word follows Zipf's Law the least.

For each distinct word `w` in this list, we know the following two properties of `w` in this list:

- Its frequency in the list (that is, the number of occurrences of it divided by the number of elements in the list), and
- Its frequency rank; that is, the number of words that occur more often than it.

In the case that two words have the same frequency, we assume the one that comes first when sorted by lexicographical order is first.

If we plot a large list of words with regular natural language distribution on a logarithmic graph with these two properties as the `x` and `y` values, we see that the points form nearly a straight line with slope of approximately `-1`. This is known as [**Zipf's Law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).

## The Challenge

You will be given a list of words `l`. Imagine each distinct word being plotted this way on a logarithmic graph. Then, the line `k` is the [Linear Regression Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) for the data set. Then, for every point `p` except the top-most ranking and most frequent point, find the vertical distance to the line `k`, and let this distance be `d`. Then, we scale the vertical distance so that points in the middle of the line will be the most heavily weighted. We do this by the following. We find the `x` coordinate of the mid-point of the line (let this be `x`). Then, half of the horizontal span of the line is `w`, the width. If we let `px` be the `x` coordinate of the point `p`, then we multiply `d` by `1 - (x - px) / w`. This value is the score.

## Input

The input will be an unordered list of words in any reasonable format you wish.

## Output

The output will be a single word indicating which word conforms the least to the "standard".

## Test Case

Input: `a a a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b c c c c c d d`
Output: `b`
See an [explanation here](https://pastebin.com/BfcD9XS8)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: 1. "Normal distribution" is a technical term: anyone who's studied statistics in English will immediately think of the distribution also known as Gaussian. IMO you should just call it Zipf's law. 2. The description given for the score is a) ambiguous and b) very odd. It's ambiguous because the question in general implies that the *absolute* difference should be what matters, but nothing explicitly says this. It's very odd because comparing gradients gives a massive bias towards the more frequent values. Why not vertical distance from the line? (And why not use the line of best fit?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I forgot that Normal Distribution is actually something. And yes, I should explicitly state absolute difference. The reason that I compare gradients is because vertical distance makes a larger difference near the ends of the line. So I will change the specs to compare vertical distance, but with a specific weighting. By the way, how is line of best fit calculated exactly? I can only find definitions where you draw a line that looks like it fits the system best.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: @PeterTaylor Okay, thanks. I've adjusted the specs to include all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

## Lock the Language!

This is a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.

### Cop's Thread:

#### Challenge:

- Write a program that given two arbitrary integers adds those and prints them to STDOUT
- In this Thread you post the fully working solution including language
- The robbers will try to find any other language where an anagram of your source code will also add two integers

  - The language has to be a different one then yours

    - Different versions of the same language don't count as different languages
- After 5 days you're code is safe and can't be cracked any more
- If you're code is cracked you mark that in the header of the answer and add a link to the crack in the robbers thread

#### Winning criteria:

- The shortest safe program (in bytes) wins.
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Robber's Thread

- The cops wrote an addition program you want to steal
- Since the cops encrypted it so you can't use the same language as the cop you stole the program from used, so you have to use an different language

  - Different versions of the same language are count as the same language
- You may use the cops character set in any order (anagram)

#### Winning criteria:

- The robber with the most cracked answers wins.

Comment: Does it need to be a "proper" anagram or can I crack an answer by finding a language in which the solution is a polyglot?

Comment: "After 5 days you're code is safe and can't be cracked any more." We usually require the cops to reveal their solution (after the period has passed) before they are considered safe.

Comment: How does it work with languages using different encodings? Is it the actual characters that should be used for the anagram or the byte-values?

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99155/42545) (Same idea, different task)

Answer (score 0):

## Comment polyglot

*From an original idea by [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)*

#### The challenge

This challenge requires you to write a polyglot which contains a comment in as many languages as possible.

The comment must say `This is a polyglot comment`.

The program must do nothing at all.

The winner is whoever writes the polyglot with most languages!

#### The rules

Your submission should consist of a full program whose source contains the text "This is a polyglot comment".

For each language of the polyglot, your code executed in that language should:

- Take no input
- Generate no errors.
- Produce either no output or the same output produced by the empty program in this language.
- Still comply to the previous rules if *any* part of `This is a polyglot comment` is removed.

Addictionally, *there can be no superflous code*. This means that it should not be possible to remove a subset of characters (outside of the comment) and still have a submission that complies to the previous rules for all the languages of the polyglot.

Ok? Ok. Now please wait a minute before running to see how many languages you can find that use `#` for comments, because we have one more rule:

We define a character of your source as **required** for a language if removing that character makes the program change its behavior for that language (this could mean for example changing its output or producing an error). *The sets of required characters for each language must all be distinct*.

#### Example submission

```
#This is a polyglot comment
```

A polyglot in Python and Brainfuck for a score of 2.

The set of required characters for Brainfuck is empty. This is perfectly valid, as long as no other set is empty.

The set of required characters for Python is composed of just the first `#`. We can't add Bash to this submission because it would share the same set.

That's all, good luck and have fun!

---

Sandbox question:

- Do you see any potential loopholes in the rules?
- Should I add some other factors to the score (like code length for example) or is the number of languages enough?
- Anything else I've missed?

Comment: I'm unsure about the definition of **required**. If I write `///This is a polyglot comment` in a language which uses `//` for comments, is `/` a required character? If I remove one `/` nothing changes, but if I remove two then I get an error. Similarly, if my language has both `#` and `//` as comments, what is the required set for `#///This is a polyglot comment` ?

Comment: a character has to be required for at least one language I think it says

Comment: @PeterTaylor you're right, this definition doesn't work. I'm having a hard time to come up with a correct one, I'll update this proposal if something suitable comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

## Operation Permutations [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

We're likely all familiar with the order of operations; the precedence rules that we use to govern basic arithmatic. Most schoolchildren are taught this order using an acronym such as "BODMAS", "BIDMAS", or "PEMDAS". There's no common consensus on the 'right' acronym to use, with the one that you learnt depending on the country you went to school in, or even the teacher who taught you. Your challenge is to determine the validity of an order of operations acronym (**O3A**), even if it's so unpronounceable that no-one would ever actually use it.

### Challenge Specification

**Input**

Input for this program is guaranteed to be exactly six characters. Your program can require upper-case, require lower-case, or be case agnostic. You may accept this input in any manner that you please.

Each character is guaranteed to be one of the following: (B, P, I, O, E, D, M, A, S). Furthermore, each character is guaranteed to appear at most only once in the input.

The following characters correspond to the following operations:

```
| Characters | Operation      |
| ---------- | -------------- |
| (B, P)     | Brackets       |
| (I, O, E)  | Exponentiation |
| D          | Division       |
| M          | Multiplication |
| A          | Addition       |
| S          | Subtraction    |
```

**Output**

Your program must yield a truthy value for a valid O3A, and a falsy value for an invalid one. Your program is not expected to handle input not matching the above specification.

**O3A Validity**

The first character in a valid O3A must correspond to 'Brackets'. Likewise, the second character in a valid O3A must correspond to 'Exponentiation'. The next two characters must correspond to 'Division' and 'Multiplication', but either order is valid as these operations are on the same precedence level. The final two characters must correspond to 'Addition' and 'Subtraction', but again, either order is valid. Any other O3As are invalid.

### Testing

**Reference Implementation**

The following Python 3 reference implementation is given for guidance. Note that while this reference implementation is case-agnostic, your program does not need to be.

```
def validate(acronym):
    acronym = acronym.upper()

    if acronym[0] not in {"B", "P"}:
        return False

    if acronym[1] not in {"I", "O", "E"}:
        return False

    if set(acronym[2:4]) != {"D", "M"}:
        return False

    if set(acronym[4:6]) != {"A", "S"}:
        return False

    return True
```

**Test Input**

```
BIDMAS => True
PEMDAS => True
PIDMSA => True
BOMDAS => True
BMIDAS => False
IBMDAS => False
BODAMS => False
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins counted in bytes.
- Standard rules and loopholes apply
- Check meta for consensus

---

### Sandbox Notes

My worry with this challenge is that it would be so trivially regex-able in something like *Retina* that it wouldn't be fun.  I'd like feedback from others about this before going live.

Comment: So: test whether an input which is known to match `[BPIOEDMAS]{6}` also matches `[BP][IOE](DM|MD)(AS|SA)`? It's possible that there's a hash function which would be shorter than an actual check, but... If you're worried about boring answers then I suggest trying to find a solution which beats the boring regex in a language you know before posting.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk I just checked, and no, it doesn't fail.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I do believe that a shorter solution than a naive regex exists, but I also don't think I'm good enough at golfing to find it. Hence I posted on sandbox in the hope that more experienced golfers would be able to better judge the golf-ability of the challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can actually shorten it slightly to `...[AS]+` since the input characters are also guaranteed to be unique (making it even harder to beat the regex solution).

Comment: @MartinEnder, in fact that becomes `[BP][IOE][MD]+[AS]+` applying the same reasoning.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh right, good catch.

Comment: I've found a trick which lets me golf 3 chars off the regex-inspired solution in CJam (which doesn't have regexes). Perl will still beat it, but there's some non-trivial interest to the question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was hoping that it would still be an interesting challenge for CJam golfers etc... I might put it up live tomorrow on the basis that it's not completely trivial (so long as it's seen as an per-language challenge).

Answer (score 0):

Haiku detector in Haiku:

I found a haiku-w detector problem, and a popularity-contest challenge for writing factorial in haiku, but not the combination.  Let's fix that:

Input: a string consisting of alphanumeric characters, standard punctuation, and |'s, where the | is used to indicate where the syllable splits are, and newlines (to indicate where the line splits are).

Output: a Truthy value if the string consists of zero or more triplets of lines where the first and third line have 4 |'s and the second line has 6 |'s.

Examples:

```
The|quick|brown|fox|jumps
O|ver|the|la|zy|dog|while
the|cat|eats|goat|cheese
```

--> True

```
This|is|not|a|hai|ku
```

--> False

```
A|B|C|d|E
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
A|B|C|D|E
Oops
```

--> False

Scoring:
   1 Point for each triplet (so a whitespace answer will automatically win with a score of 0; I'm open to suggestions on how to mitigate this); this is code golf so lowest score wins.

Determining if code is valid haiku:
Must consist of lines of code consisting of 5/7/5 syllables (with an optional empty line in between triplets)

Numbers and Variable names are read as written in standard English.  If you want to get fancy and use a word that can be read as different number of syllables (e.g. coop as in chicken coop vs coop as in the short form of cooperative that isn't always rendered using an umlaut), have at it.

Special characters:

> ```
>   ( is either 2,3 or 4 syllables (paren, left paren, open paren)
>   ) is either 2, or 3 syllables (paren, right paren, close paren)
>   ! is 1 or 5 syllables (bang, not, or exclamation point)
>   . is 1 (dot)
>   # is 1 (hash or pound)
>   $ is 2 or 3 (dollar or dollar sign)
>   % is 2 or 3 (percent or percent sign)
>   - is 1 or 2 (dash, hyphen, minus)
>   + is 1 or 2 (plus, plus sign)
>   ^ is 2 (caret or xor)
>   & is 3 (ampersand)
>   * is 1 (star)
>   [ is 2,3,4,5 (bracket, open bracket, left bracket, square bracket, open square bracket, etc.)
>   ], {, and } are likewise 2,3,4,5
>   _ is 3 (underscore)
>   = is 2 (equals)
>   : is 2 (colon)
>   ; is 4 (semicolon)
>   > is 2 or 3 (greater or greater than)
>   < is 2 or 3
>   --> is either combination of two -'s and one > or 2 (arrow)
>   , is 2 (comma)
>   / is 1 or 3 (slash or forward slash)
>   \ is 2 (backslash)
>   | is 1 or 4 (pipe or vertical bar)
>   ? is 2 or 3 (question or question mark)
>   @ is 1 (at)
>   ~ is 2 (squiggle or tilde)
>   ` is 2 (backtick)
>   ' is 1 or 3 (quote or single quote)
>   " is 3 (double quote)
> ```

Note that for everything but quote, if you use the same symbol 2 (or more times), you can instead say double symbol (or triple or whatever), e.g. && can be either 5 or 6 syllables)

I think that's all the punctuation... other unprintable characters are banned unless you can give a compelling argument on how many syllables it should be (and if I missed any pronounciation alternatives or other punctuation, let me know)

Answer (score 0):

### Golf the Stack Exchange code block

The standard Stack Exchange code block button / hot key prepends 4 spaces to each line, unless they all begin with 4 spaces, in which case it removes them. Additionally, it avoids changing the first or last lines if they are empty. But why stop at the first or last lines? Markdown is quite happy if intervening empty lines remain empty. As this saves bytes, I want you to write as short a program (or function) as you can that follows this enhanced behaviour:

- All empty lines should remain unchanged
- If all other lines begin with 4 spaces, then remove 4 spaces from them
- Otherwise, prepend 4 spaces to each of them

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Note that should your answer itself contain a blank line, you should ensure that there are no spaces on that line in your formatted code block.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115863/62131) (and currently active). I'd say this challenge should be explicitly described as a followup to that one, because it's basically "much the same task but harder".

Answer (score 0):

## Lazy programmers need help versioning!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

So here's a question, which is related to a recent problem I had while doing some data processing. I think it is good practice to include version numbers in file names to prevent data being overwritten and so you can see how things have changed with each version but I'm lazy so want it automating!

### Your challenge

Take a full Windows file path and either increment the file version, or if there is no version, make it version 1.

### Input

A full Windows file path, that includes the file extension.

### Output

The original file path with the file version, incremented appropriately.

### Rules

- The version is determined by an underscore followed by a single digit, i.e `_1` for version 1.
- For a file that already have a version, it will only be in the range `1-8`, so you only ever have to deal with single digit file versions.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422)
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Please provide explanations of your code so others can learn form it and if possible, links to an online interpreter such as [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases

```
Case 1
Input:  C:\Foo\Bar.txt
Output: C:\Foo\Bar_1.txt

Case 2
Input:  C:\notsortedfile_version_1_new_5.docx
Output: C:\notsortedfile_version_1_new_6.docx

Case 3
Input:  D:\a\very\deep\file\567234.pdf
Output: D:\a\very\deep\file\567234_1.pdf

Case 4
Input:  Z:\Storage\Somefile_2017-04-11.txt
Output: Z:\Storage\Somefile_2017-04-11_1.txt

Case 5
Input:  Z:\Storage\I.Like.Dots.txt
Output: Z:\Storage\I.Like.Dots_1.txt
```

### Sandbox Questions

Not sure if this is dupe of [Please release me!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102531/please-release-me/102532#102532)

Any feedback welcome.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. My opinions: You shouldn't let the test cases be dependent on OS. Just stick with one, the challenge is to modify a string, it doesn't really depend on which OS you're on. Personlly, I'd skip the `1-8` limitation. I think it would be more fun to go from `file_9` to `file_10`. People (including you) might disagree with me though.

Comment: Also, I though version control was handled this way: `filename.xyz` -> `filename_new.xyz` -> `filename_new_1.xyz` (remember to rename the previous to: `filename_new_OLD.xyz`). And of course versions such as `filename_new_2_backup.xyz`, `filename_final_version.xyz` -> `filename_final_version_2.xyz`.

Comment: Which is why need to get some code to do it for us :)

Comment: Will file names only ever contain a `.`?

Comment: @Shaggy It could be any valid windows file path so yes, I've added a test case to cover it.

Comment: Test case: `c:\foo`?

Answer (score 0):

## Swipe over the keyboard

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(I'm not a native speaker so any good alternative for swipe is highly appreciated)

You have a keyboard in front of you and you swipe over the keyboard from left to right with your whole hand. Your task is to simulate the output.
The keyboard is represented with 4 arrays (here is an example of a german keyboard layout, you are free to choose any other layout):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,ß,´]
[q,w,e,r,t,z,u,i,o,p,ü,+]
[a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,ö,ä,#]
[<,y,x,c,v,b,n,m,,,.,-]
```

Now choose randomly one character of the first column `[1,q,a,<]`. Pop the chosen key and do the same with the newly created first column. For example the first key was `q`, the new first column will be `[1,w,a,<]`. The popped key will be printed out or skipped. Repeat it until your arrays are empty.

The rules are the following:

- You can represent the keyboard with 4 arrays matching the 4 rows on your keyboard. For example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,ß,´]` would be my first row (german keyboard layout). Choose the keyboard layout you want, but it has to include all letters and numbers
- There is no need to represent non-printable keys like tabulator, shift, backspace, ... so in general you won't hit the first and last column and the last row (you won't hit space too)
- Since you are swiping from left to right, the probability to hit a previously located key is 0. So if the key 5 is pressed, the keys 1-4 won't be pressed anymore.
- Each key needs to have a probability `P!=0` to be pressed
- Each key needs to have a probability `P!=0` to be skipped
- The rows are independent
- There is no input

### Open questions

- Should I allow only one keyboard type?
- Are there still rules that need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

### CRC Collision

Your task: Accept a string (one could also include symbols in the string, does not have to be only alphabets and numbers) of any length as input, calculate 16bit CRC for the given string. Output a string of same length which gives you the exact same CRC sum.

Example:

```
Input Text: Hello World!
Caclculated CRC : 0xF444

Output Text (with same CRC): DW=9Mzk?7P4y
```

You may use in-built CRC libraries to calculate.

Shortest code that fulfills the requirement wins!

Comment: What's the winning criterion? Can we use any 16-bit CRC or does it have to be a specific one? Which characters/bytes are allowed in input/output?What should happen if there isn't another string of the same length with the same checksum?

Comment: @Dennis Any 16-bit CRC routine would do! It has to be a string i.e ASCII characters. The input string should be minimum 3 bytes long, there should be a collision right?

Comment: I think so, yes, but I'm not sure if the output can only consist of ASCII characters.

Comment: So i guess non ASCII characters are acceptable too!

Comment: @Dennis Is there a suggestion to make it a little harder may be? Or can i put it like this as a challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## Golf me a golf-lang

In any programing language of your choice write me an interpreter (or compiler targetting a reasonable pre-existing binary) for a golfing language. You will be scored based on a combination of the length of the interpreter and the golfiness of programs in your (user created language). In particular your goal will be to minimize the following formula.

```
max((Interpreter Length in bytes),512)/16-25*("checkmarks")
```

A good answer will not only contain an interpreter, but also contain code samples and documentation to encourage use of your language.

The number of "checkmarks" a language has earned is the number of times an answer in your language has beat or tied with the best answer (out of languages which are submissions to this challenge) to an open, positively voted (score of +1 or higher) question (whatever the win criterion) which postdate your language and were not asked by its creator(s) (in the event of a community wiki submission).

Your language will now be in a meta-competition around stack exchange, and you can earn checkmarks if other people choose to win other challenges with your competition.

---

Note that use of eval (or similar) is banned. 
You may write your interpreter/compiler in any preexisting programming language, and your language that you implement may be as similar as you wish to currently existing programming languages.

[language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I'm worried that crafting a good solution to this will take a lot of time (thus meaning that late answers are fairly common) – it *is* [tag:language-design], after all – but the victory condition means that there's a hard limit to how long answers can arrive. Perhaps the languages should be somehow tested on how they fare on questions that postdate the languages themselves?

Comment: If a challenge is selected which a language can't implement (e.g. one which requires a GUI, but the language only does I/O via stdio), how is it scored?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I decided to go a completely different way, challenges your language cant complete neither hurt or help you.

Comment: @ais523 I restructured the challenge, I liked the idea of being tested based on how you fare on languages that post date yourself, this way later answers are at a disadvantage, but they can still compete (and win).

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons to not award an accepted answer tick (e.g. some challenges have a reason to preserve the sort order), so not all challenges will have one. Change that to count questions on which your language has the best answer or tied for the best answer (based on the challenge's victory condition), and I like the new scoring.

Answer (score 0):

## Display a fractal maze

Based on this Puzzling.SE question: [Alice and the Fractal Hedge Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37675/16128).

Given a description of a maze as input, output a [graphical / ASCII-art ?] representation of the maze.

[image: Maze layout]

For the purpose of this challenge, all inner mazes are assumed to be smaller copies of the original maze. So a top-down view of the above maze would look like this:

[image: top-down view showing recursion]

### Input:

Input will be given as a list of connections between different ports of the same level of the maze and the inner sub-mazes.

One list of connections for the above maze would be the following:

```
1,12,a5,a12
```

This is because, in the maze, ports 1 and 12 are connected to each other, and they are also connected to ports 5 and 12 of sub-maze A.

A full description of the above example maze would be the following:

```
a3      (note that a connection by itself means this is the starting point)
1,12,a5,a12
2,8,10,a9,c4
3,b1,b4
4,b5,b6
5,d4,d5
6,d8
7,b7,d10
9,c7,c11
11,a10
b8,d1,d3
b11,b12
c2,c12
d11,d12
```

### Flexibility:

You may take each port like above or as a tuple with numbers instead of letters, such as using `0` for the outer maze and numbering the inner mazes sequentially. So the following would all be acceptable for a line:

```
2,8,10,a9,c4
[2,8,10,(1,9),(3,4)]
[2,8,10,('A',9),('C',4)]
[(0,2),(0,8),(0,10),(1,9),(3,4)]
[(0,2),(0,8),(0,10),(-1,9),(-3,4)]
```

The starting point will be by itself. You can take it in the list as a port by itself, or as a separate parameter. The starting position will always be an entrance to a sub-maze. Each port will be listed at most once in the input. Note that not all ports have to be listed, as there are some dead ends.

### Output:

Output a representation of the maze given. Note that mazes may require bridging of paths (crossing without connection).

## Note: [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) or [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) ?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)

Comment: I think this challenge might be more interesting if it where about solving fractal mazes instead of displaying them.

Comment: That was going to be a second, separate challenge.

Answer (score 0):

**Which answer is correct?**

I've posted an [earlier version of this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116374/which-answer-is-correct) already; but now hoping to refine here before correcting the original post.  Thanks all in advance for any advise.

---

I saw this elegant logic puzzle on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217248/which-answer-in-this-list-is-the-correct-answer-to-this-question.):

```
Which answer in this list is the correct answer to this question?

 1. All of the below.
 2. None of the below.
 3. All of the above.
 4. One of the above.
 5. None of the above.
 6. None of the above.
```

One user submitted a [nice answer in code](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217333) (quoted below), which inspired this puzzle.

**Task:**

Write code which determines the answer to the above logic puzzle according to standard Code Golf rules (i.e. a working solution with the minimum number of characters wins).

The input should be a sequence (i.e. ordered list / array) with each item in that sequence representing one of the given statements.
Each items in the list should hold 2 values:
- the first representing `All`, `One`, or `None`.
- the second representing `above`, or `below`.

The result should be a list/array of the indices of any correct answers.

The following test scenarios are considered invalid; i.e. your code would not be expected to handle such data:

- A statement is the first statement in the sequence and refers to `the above`, it evaluates to false.
- A statement is the last statement in teh sequence and refers to `the below`, it evaluates to false.

We should be optimistic about results.  i.e. given the following, the program would return `1, 2`:

```
1. all of the below
2. one of the above
```

When contradictions occur, neither statement is correct.  i.e. the following would return a blank string.

```
1. none of the below
2. none of the above
```

**Code for Referenced Answer**

```
// gcc ImpredictivePropositionalLogic1.c -o ImpredictivePropositionalLogic1.exe -std=c99 -Wall -O3

/*
Which answer in this list is the correct answer to this question?

(a) All of the below.
(b) None of the below.
(c) All of the above.
(d) One of the above.
(e) None of the above.
(f) None of the above.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define iff(x, y) ((x)==(y))

int main() {
  printf("a b c d e f\n");
  for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b <= 1; b++)
  for (int c = 0; c <= 1; c++)
  for (int d = 0; d <= 1; d++)
  for (int e = 0; e <= 1; e++)
  for (int f = 0; f <= 1; f++) {
    int Ra = iff(a, b && c && d && e && f);
    int Rb = iff(b, !c && !d && !e && !f);
    int Rc = iff(c, a && b);
    int Rd = iff(d, (a && !b && !c) || (!a && b && !c) || (!a && !b && c));
    int Re = iff(e, !a && !b && !c && !d);
    int Rf = iff(f, !a && !b && !c && !d && !e);

    int R = Ra && Rb && Rc && Rd && Re && Rf;
    if (R) printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Test Cases**

To represent the conditions in these test cases I've used the following convention:

- `[`...`]` to represent the entire sequence
- `(match,direction)` to represent each item where match and direction have values:

Match:

- `0` - None of the
- `1` - One of the
- `2` - All of the

Direction:

- `0` - below
- `1` - above

**1. The Original**

```
[
    (2,0)  //all of the below
    ,(0,0) //none of the below
    ,(2,1) //all of the above
    ,(1,1) //one of the above
    ,(0,1) //none of the above
    ,(0,1) //none of the above
]

//expected answer is 5
```

**2. Both**

```
[
    (2,0)  //all of the below
    ,(1,1) //one of the above
]

//expected answer is 1, 2
```

**3. Neither**

```
[
    (0,0)  //none of the below
    ,(0,1) //none of the above
]

//expected answer is (nothing)
```

**4. Simple**

```
[
    (2,0)  //all of the below
    ,(0,1) //none of the above
]

//expected answer is 2
```

Comment: You should probably allow the output to be a list of possible answers, rather than requiring a string like you implicitly do at the moment.

Comment: I believe you get only answer like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1dd67fc53217c8338da0c9106fa0f492a990833 First column the possible answer if only one is true as binary in decimal value second column is which answer are true also in binary as decimal value and in the third column only the answer where second column is equal to first column. I like this kind of problems

Comment: Thanks @ais523; amended

Answer (score 0):

Help me discover myself!

Hola,
People call me `file`. At any point of time, all I know is how people compile me. Some use `gcc` some use `gpp` and some `Java` and some even `csc`. I couldn't really figure out who I am with just this info!

All I can do for you to help me is show a snippet inside me for you to find out the programming language. If you couldn't find with the snippet(the snippet will not have any incomplete line of code), only then can I share how programmers compile me.

And yes, you are brilliant enough to find out the language in which the program in me is written!

I may have...

**Example1:**

Input1:

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

Output1:

```
c|cpp
```

Input2:

```
gpp
```

Output2:
    c++

**or**

Input2:

```
gcc
```

Output2:

```
c
```

**Example 2:**

Input1:

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){return 0;}
```

Output1:

```
c++
```

**Example3:**

Input1:

```
main(){}
```

Output1:

```
c
```

- the above example can't possibly be java because the mandatory return type for the method in java is missing.

**Example4:**

Input1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){}
```

Output1:

```
c
```

**Example5:**

Input1:

```
class hola{public static void main(){}}
```

Output1:

```
java
```

**Example6:**

Input1:

```
class Hola{public static void Main(){}}
```

Output1:

```
c#
```

Oh yeah, I also know few things that might be helpful for you. The snippet that I'm allowed to share is only headers and the main function - first function that is called when program is executed.

And also, there are some conventions.

And then,

- c    - return type for main is not mandatory, standard header is stdio.h
- c++ return type is mandatory, standard header is iosstream
- c# - Main is a title - first letter is caps!

**Input format** Any code snippet it is more than enough if your answer identifies the above given six example snippet.

**Output format** programming language in which the snippet possibly fits in.

This is code golf and hence shortest code in each language wins!

Comment: How many languages - and which ones - do we need to support, and to which accuracy? Or, is it sufficient to hard-code the output for some given list of possible inputs?

Comment: its enough if the answer supports the given input! And accuracy is 100% because, there is a certain restriction by languages and yeah I'll add that to the question

Comment: I don't think I understand what the challenge is asking. "Assume the input is one of your choosing, and output the corresponding (single, hardcodeable) language"?

Comment: one of six sample inputs and identify the language(c,c++,java or c# - yeah hardcodable).

Comment: so, "hash the input and look up in a six-element table". Not fun.

Comment: not really. There is a trick. If the input contains `Class` it goes without saying the the language is `C#` but if the input is `int main` the language can either be `c` or c++. It will a set of if and else'.

Comment: Yeah, I could have a case statement with six regexes, but `%w{c java c++ - - - python}[i.size%13]` is much shorter.

Comment: sorry I dont get what you mean by  `"input length % 13"`

Comment: I don't know what sources you've been reading about C#, but the capital `Class` will give a syntax error.

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh yeah you are right. I dunno why I ever typed that. Its been a while since I programmed using c#. I've edited the post.

Comment: @JanDvorak you have edited your comment, but I still dont get it.

Comment: Answer #1600...

Comment: @programmer5000  don't get it. Can you please be more elaborate!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran oh, I was just remarking that we were on our #1600th sandbox submission. Now it's 1602...

Answer (score 0):

## Generate a Voronoi Diagram

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

### Challenge

Given a list of coordinates and colours of points, output a 300px by 300px Voronoi Diagram.

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

***To be expanded***

Comment: output a what???

Comment: @Titus [A Voronoi Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_Diagram). I'll add an explanation when I have time

Comment: Five months later...

Comment: @Gryphon It's a looong expansion ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate Call-Changes

Before learning to ring methods, novice bell-ringers usually first learn something called call-changes. This is basically a sequence of permutations (the changes), each one obtained from the previous by exchanging a pair of adjacent bells (the call).

The bells always begin in ascending pitch number order (which is actually descending pitch order). Each exchange (call) can be expressed in one of two different ways, depending on the whim of the conductor. Exchanges always use the bell's pitch number, regardless of the bell's current position.

1. The exchange can be expressed as a pair of adjacent bell numbers in sequence. The first of the pair is always immediately before the second of the pair. The two bells simply exchange places, so the first of the pair ends up immediately after the second of the pair.
2. - The exchange can be expressed as a bell number plus a second bell number which is two places before the first bell. The (unnamed) intervening bell and the first bell exchange places. This also results in the first input bell ending up immediately after the second input bell.
   - The above expression cannot be used to move a bell into first (lead) place, because there is no bell for it to end up after. You therefore need to accept an alternate way of expressing that the first two bells change places. Note that this must still refer to the pitch number of the bell in second place, but this might be achieved e.g. by having a sentinel value for the second bell, or by omitting it completely. (In real call-changes the call is "[number] lead!" rather than "[number] to [number]!".)

Your other input will be the number (not list) of bells in the sequence. You can assume that this will not be more than 9 (but supporting larger numbers may get you more upvotes). Here is a worked example showing the list of calls in both of the above formats and the desired output:

```
Call 1  Call 2  Output
(5 bells input  12345)
12      20*     21345
34      41      21435
14      42      24135
24      40*     42135
21      14      41235
41      10*     14235
42      21      12435
43      32      12345

*example representation.
```

Your program or function should output the result after each change. (Showing the initial permutation is permitted but not necessary.) Input and output can be any reasonable method, e.g. nested array of numbers or list of strings (note that if you use strings and want to support more than 9 bells then the next three bells are traditionally numbered `0`, `E` and `T`). You can assume that all inputs follow the above pattern (or your custom representation for calling the seconds place bell into first place).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I can't work out what the example is showing. Specifically: what input should the function/program take and what output should it produce?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Except for the first `12345` row, which is only there to try to help demonstrate the mechanics, the left column contains the result. However for each result there are two acceptable inputs (this is just a fact of life, not an attempt to make the question more complex); these are shown in the other two columns.

Comment: So e.g. the input is `"42135", "24"` and the output is `"41235"`?

Comment: No, the input is `5, "12", "34", "14", "24", "21", "41", "42", "43"` and the output is `"21345"..."42135", "41235"..."12345"`.

Comment: Could you edit the question to make that clearer?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hopefully my rewrite is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Autocomplete Fun [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Your task is to create a program which, given an input string, will output the first Google autocomplete result for that search. The format of input/output is up to you.

### Rules

1. Your program must take 1 input, a string, and output the top Google autocomplete/auto-fill suggestions result. The format of input/output is up to you. Just be sure to mention what your I/O format is.
2. Obviously, accessing the Internet is allowed.
3. URL shorteners (like bit.ly, TinyURL, etc.) are strictly *disallowed*. You should fetch your autocomplete results from this URL: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=your_browser&q=your_query. You are allowed to assume any browser name for `client`. In the [program I wrote](https://gist.github.com/ckjbgames/f7bfa353e639f4a449fc57ab0a7befd3), I assume Chrome. Any browser name or string should work.
4. Please provide an explanation of how your program works. It is not mandatory, but I strongly advise it.
5. All standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden*.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: I think you technically need to allow internet access in the question.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony You are so right. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Find the Calling Pattern

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

I've written a program to add two numbers `a` and `b`:

```
f=lambda:lambda a:lambda b:lambda:a+b
```

This has a very specific calling pattern. It must be called as:

```
f()(a)(b)()
```

In this case, it was fairly clear, but sometimes the calling pattern can be more complicated:

```
f(a,None)()("","","")([0,0],b)(())()
```

In essence, this challenge is about the cops trying to obfuscate this calling pattern, and the robbers trying to find it.

### Rules for Cops:

#### Calling patterns:

- The function must only need to be called up to 5 times to give the answer.
- For the purposes of this challenge, a *false-unit* is `None`, `""`, `[]`, `0`, or `()`.
- A valid argument to the curried function in the calling pattern is either:

  - a false-unit,
  - a list or tuple containing one to five false units, or
  - one of the actual numbers to be added (represented by `a` and `b`).
- Each time it is called, it should only take up to five arguments.
- The calling pattern can change based on what arguments are passed to it. Be creative!
- `a` and `b` must each appear once in the calling pattern.

Examples of valid calling patterns:

```
f(a,b)
f("",a)(b,[0,0])
f(a)("",(),[None],[0,()])(b)()
```

Examples of invalid calling patterns:

```
f(a,b,0,0,"",[]) # too many arguments
f(a,[(),[],"",(),[],""])(b) # too many elements in [(),[],"",(),[],""]
f(a) # b is not passed
f([a,b]) # a and b may not be contained in a list
f((0,[None,""]),a)(b) # [None,""] is not a false-unit
```

For your submission, you must post a lambda that, when called according to your calling pattern, evaluates to `a + b`.

You can assume that `a` and `b` are both positive and that `a + b < 2147483647` (the highest signed 32-bit integer).

Your submission is safe if it is not cracked by a robber in one week.

### Rules for Robbers

To crack a cop's submission, you must post a submission which takes two inputs and returns a string showing how to call the cop's submission to coerce it into adding your two inputs. For example, if this was a cop's submission:

```
lambda:lambda x,z:lambda y:x+(y*(z==0))
```

This could be your crack:

```
lambda a, b: "f()(%s, 0)(%s)" % (a, b)
```

### Sandbox Notes

- Is there anything I should clarify? Should I add more examples?
- Should I try to make this language agnostic or restrict it to Python?
- Is this too weighted towards one side (is it too easy for the cops or the robbers?)
- Are there any additional restrictions that could make it more fair?

Comment: Can you give an example of a cops submission that might be hard to crack?

Comment: Without a language restriction, some may call Currying a non-observable requirement.

Comment: @ATaco Which is why I was thinking of restricting it to Python.

Comment: often, after a certain time (a week, for example,) A cop's submission is considered "safe", and they reveal their solution (if they want). You may want to mention/implement something like this

Comment: @MistahFiggins Added.

Comment: I don't think the example works.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Edited.

Comment: That's still broken except in the special case that `y == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

### Excel NORMSINV function

Implement the excel NORMSINV function in your favourite language, shortest code wins

Build in functions and standard loopholes are not allowed

Loss of precision is also not allowed

Reference C Implementation

```
/*
 * Original C++ implementation found at http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=38771
 * C# implementation found at http://weblogs.asp.net/esanchez/archive/2010/07/29/a-quick-and-dirty-implementation-of-excel-norminv-function-in-c.aspx
 *     Compute the quantile function for the normal distribution.
 *
 *     For small to moderate probabilities, algorithm referenced
 *     below is used to obtain an initial approximation which is
 *     polished with a final Newton step.
 *
 *     For very large arguments, an algorithm of Wichura is used.
 *
 *  REFERENCE
 *
 *     Beasley, J. D. and S. G. Springer (1977).
 *     Algorithm AS 111: The percentage points of the normal distribution,
 *     Applied Statistics, 26, 118-121.
 *
 *      Wichura, M.J. (1988).
 *      Algorithm AS 241: The Percentage Points of the Normal Distribution.
 *      Applied Statistics, 37, 477-484.
 */

#include <math.h>

double normsInv(double p, double mu, double sigma)
{
    if (p < 0 || p > 1)
    {
        printf("The probality p must be bigger than 0 and smaller than 1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (sigma < 0)
    {
        printf("The standard deviation sigma must be positive");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (p == 0)
    {
        return -1e100;
    }
    if (p == 1)
    {
        return 1e100;
    }
    if (sigma == 0)
    {
        return mu;
    }

    double q, r, val;

    q = p - 0.5;

    /*-- use AS 241 --- */
    /* double ppnd16_(double *p, long *ifault)*/
    /*      ALGORITHM AS241  APPL. STATIST. (1988) VOL. 37, NO. 3
            Produces the normal deviate Z corresponding to a given lower
            tail area of P; Z is accurate to about 1 part in 10**16.
    */
    if (fabs(q) <= .425)
    {/* 0.075 <= p <= 0.925 */
        r = .180625 - q * q;
        val =
               q * (((((((r * 2509.0809287301226727 +
                          33430.575583588128105) * r + 67265.770927008700853) * r +
                        45921.953931549871457) * r + 13731.693765509461125) * r +
                      1971.5909503065514427) * r + 133.14166789178437745) * r +
                    3.387132872796366608)
               / (((((((r * 5226.495278852854561 +
                        28729.085735721942674) * r + 39307.89580009271061) * r +
                      21213.794301586595867) * r + 5394.1960214247511077) * r +
                    687.1870074920579083) * r + 42.313330701600911252) * r + 1);
    }
    else
    { /* closer than 0.075 from {0,1} boundary */

        /* r = min(p, 1-p) < 0.075 */
        if (q > 0)
            r = 1 - p;
        else
            r = p;

        r = sqrt(-log(r));
        /* r = sqrt(-log(r))  <==>  min(p, 1-p) = exp( - r^2 ) */

        if (r <= 5)
        { /* <==> min(p,1-p) >= exp(-25) ~= 1.3888e-11 */
            r += -1.6;
            val = (((((((r * 7.7454501427834140764e-4 +
                       .0227238449892691845833) * r + .24178072517745061177) *
                     r + 1.27045825245236838258) * r +
                    3.64784832476320460504) * r + 5.7694972214606914055) *
                  r + 4.6303378461565452959) * r +
                 1.42343711074968357734)
                / (((((((r *
                         1.05075007164441684324e-9 + 5.475938084995344946e-4) *
                        r + .0151986665636164571966) * r +
                       .14810397642748007459) * r + .68976733498510000455) *
                     r + 1.6763848301838038494) * r +
                    2.05319162663775882187) * r + 1);
        }
        else
        { /* very close to  0 or 1 */
            r += -5;
            val = (((((((r * 2.01033439929228813265e-7 +
                       2.71155556874348757815e-5) * r +
                      .0012426609473880784386) * r + .026532189526576123093) *
                    r + .29656057182850489123) * r +
                   1.7848265399172913358) * r + 5.4637849111641143699) *
                 r + 6.6579046435011037772)
                / (((((((r *
                         2.04426310338993978564e-15 + 1.4215117583164458887e-7) *
                        r + 1.8463183175100546818e-5) * r +
                       7.868691311456132591e-4) * r + .0148753612908506148525)
                     * r + .13692988092273580531) * r +
                    .59983220655588793769) * r + 1);
        }

        if (q < 0.0)
        {
            val = -val;
        }
    }

    return mu + sigma * val;
}
```

Comment: A reference implementation is not a specification.

Comment: Yeah there are people who don't speak C.

Comment: @Peter, do you have any suggestions on how I can create a specification for this? Do you think people will be interested or is this a dead end?

Comment: 1. Define the function: what are the inputs? What does the output mean? On the basis of some quick Googling I understand that it's an offset inverse of `erf`? But there seems to be disagreement about how many input parameters it takes. 2. Be explicit about the numerical analytic requirements. I'm not sure what "*Loss of precision is also not allowed*" means: that answers must avoid subtractions of values of similar magnitude? 3. With respect to interest, the thematically related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9070/194 got a few answers.

Answer (score 0):

## To Polar and Back

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

### Background

There are 2 main ways to represent a single point on a plane:

- in Cartesian form, with an x and y value,
- and in Polar form, with an angle and a magnitude

For example, the point `(5, 5)` can also be represented with the angle `π / 4` and magnitude `5 * sqrt(2)`

In this challenge, we will be using radians, and not degrees.

### Conversion

This challenge deals with the mapping of Polar form onto a Cartesian grid, by using the angle as the x value, and the magnitude as the y value.

For example, to change the point `(sqrt(3), 1)` into Polar form and back, we first convert it into polar form, with an angle of `π / 6` and magnitude of `2`.

Then, these values are mapped into Cartesian form, yielding the Cartesian point `(π/6, 2)`.

### The Challenge

Create a program or function that, given a rectangle in Cartesian form, outputs it's area after it has been converted to Polar form and mapped back onto the Cartesian plane by equating angle with x and magnitude with y.

#### Input

The input will be a rectangle in Cartesian form whose legs are parallel to the x and y axes. Also, all 4 corners will be in the first quadrant, meaning that all x and y values will be strictly positive.

This means that you may take

- The Cartesian coordinates of all 4 corners
- The Cartesian coordinates of opposite corners
- The Cartesian coordinates of one corner, and a width and height value

or some other reasonable form, such as a rectangle object.
The important thing is that you don't take Polar coordinates as input.

You can take the points or values in any order you choose.

Please include the input format you used in your answer.

#### Output

Output will be a single, decimal number rounded to at least the hundredth's place (2 digits after the decimal).

### Explained Example

Note: For the sake of clarity, I will use symbols like `π` or `sqrt(3)` instead of their decimal equivalents.

Also keep in mind that this is probably one of many ways to go about this problem, and it doesn't matter what method you use to find the area as long as you do. This example is mostly to explain the above by showing it in action.

Anyways, here is out input, in the form of 4 points:

`(1, sqrt(3)), (4, sqrt(3)), (1, 1), (4, 1)`

First, we might convert each point into polar form, and map that back onto the Cartesian plane:

```
(x, y)       -> (angle, magnitude)
(1, sqrt(3)) -> (π/3, 2)
(4, sqrt(3)) -> (arctan(sqrt(3)/4), sqrt(19))
(1, 1)       -> (π/4, sqrt(2))
(4, 1)       -> (arctan(1/4), sqrt(17))
```

This should be relatively easy using trigonometry and the Pythagorean theorem.

These new Cartesian points give us the corners of our new shape, which looks something like this:

[image: courtesy of http://www.meta-calculator.com]

Notice that the sides are not straight, meaning you will have to figure out how to get the equations for the sides as well as how to find the area. I'll leave that up to you.

In any case, the area of this shape is about `0.81810689`, but you only need to print `0.82` (without the leading `0`, if you prefer).

### Other Test Cases

The input will be taken in the form of 4 points, in reading order (left to right, then top to bottom)

```
input -> output
(1, 1.732), (4, 1.732), (1, 1), (4, 1) -> 0.82
```

**Sandbox:** I will add more test cases later - any suggestions about certain edge cases I should include would be helpful.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Standard loopholes, as always, apply.

### Sandbox

- Any name ideas?
- Any tags I should add/remove?
- Suggestions/help with creating test cases?
- Is the explanation sufficient?
- Should I change the accuracy requirement to 3 digits after the decimal point, or would that be too hard?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how the edges should be curved. Additionally, I think you should require the program to use the maximum precision that the language can handle, but I'm not sure how well that would work.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino The edges curve because more points on the straight line lie in a given angle when the segment looked at is farther from the point closest to the origin. In other words, as the line gets farther from the axes, the line gets closer to parallel with a ray extending from the origin to the line. This means that the line on the new graph will be closer to vertical when it gets closer to the axis (at angles `0` or `π/2`, depending on whether the original line is vertical or horizontal). Hope this helps! Also, not sure about the accuracy yet, so I'm going to leave it as it is for now.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. And yeah, I'd do what you're doing and see if other people make suggestions on the accuracy aspect.

Comment: "*Create a program or function that, given a rectangle in Cartesian form, output it's area after it has been converted to polar form and back.*" Since the conversion is a bijection, converting to polar form and back leaves it unchanged, so it's just a case of finding the area of the rectangle. That doesn't seem to be what the example does, though, so I have to say that the spec is not clear.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, this is poorly worded. It should say something like "given a rectangle in Cartesian form, output it's area after it has been converted to Polar form and mapped back onto the Cartesian plane by equating angle with x and magnitude with y"

Answer (score 0):

## Electron Configurations: Orbitals

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

### Challenge

Given an elements atomic number as input, output its short electronic configuration.

### Explanation

http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/elstructs.html

To come

### Examples

#### Sodium: 11

```
[Ne] 3s1
```

#### Hydrogen: 1

```
1s1
```

#### Helium: 2

```
1s2
```

or

```
[He]
```

#### Vanadium: 23

```
[Ar] 4s2 3d3
```

#### Selenium: 34

```
[Ar] 4s2 3d10 4p4
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Do we have to worry about unstable isotopes undergoing Beta Decay? ;) Nice challenge btw!

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37657/194

Answer (score 0):

## Variably Incremented Chained Ranges  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task will be, given a well-formed input string `s`, to parse it as a range, with special properties:

1. A traditional range is defined as `a..b = [a, a+1, .., b-1, b]`.
2. An incremental range is an extension of the traditional range in the format `a.c.b`.

   - The format above uses `a` and `b` in the traditional sense, but it will use `c` as the step.
   - That is to say `1.2.5 = [1,3,5]` and `a.c.b = [a, a+c, .., b iff b-a is divisble by c]`
   - This means that `0.2.5 = [0, 2, 4]` because `b-a % c != 0`.
3. The ranges are chain-able, meaning that `a..b..c..d..e..f..g..h..i` is valid.

   - Always should be handled left-to-right.
   - The chain should always be continued from the end of the last range.
   - `0.2.5..3` is not `[0,2,4,5,4,3]` it is `[0,2,4,3]`.
4. The format of the range may be `a.c.b` or `a..b`, absence of `c` means `c = 1`.

## I & O Gaurantees

- `c <= difference(b, a)`, you will never see something like `1.100.2`.
- `a` and `b` are positive integers or 0, this makes crap easier
- Notice, however, that neither `a > b` nor `a < b` are guaranteed, both are acceptable.
- `a, b and c` will always be integer values, floats aren't supported.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence), lowest byte count wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Give counterexamples to thesis that prime numbers are finite.

It is known since antiquity that there are infinite prime numbers, first proved by Euclid. An unorthodox yet brief formulation of this proof was [recently posted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268344) on MathExchange:

> There are infinitely many primes, if not, multiply all and add 1.

## Challenge

Given a prime number `N`, output a prime number created by multiplying  it with all lower primes and adding one, i. e. `(2*3*5*...*N) + 1`. In other words, if someone claimed that `N` is the largest finite number, you have to give a counterexample Euclid would likely compute to prove them false.

You don't have to consider input number that is not a prime.

Your representation of a number must have a range of 32-bit signed integers or larger.

You can use floating point representation as long as your code uses `int`-specific operations (e.g. no `double`-specific bit-fu).

Shortest code wins, standard loopholes forbidden. You may use a lookup table of primes.

## Example Input and Output

```
2 → 3          // because             2 + 1 = 3
3 → 7          // because           3*2 + 1 = 7
5 → 31         // because         5*3*2 + 1 = 31
13 → 30031     // because 13*11*7*5*3*2 + 1 = 30031
31 → 223092871 // (largest possible output within `int32` range)
```

## Note

This is very similar to, yet not identical with [A006862](https://oeis.org/A006862): your solution must output a number belonging to that sequence. The difference is that your solution must work for inputs that are primes, while A006862 recognizes any natural number (including 0).

If your solution is function `f()`, the following equivalence must be true:

```
A006862(n) = M <=> f(A000040(n)) = M
```

[A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040) is the sequence of primes, therefore `A000040(n)` can be read as "n-th prime number".

Comment: In its current state I would have to vote to close this as unclear what you're asking. 1. What should the output be for input 13? 2. Why is the output for 31 not 200560490131? 3. How does it differ from A006862? If these issues are fixed then it likely becomes a duplicate of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11638/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I hope my edit clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Do you realise that 30031 = 59 * 509 and is therefore not prime?

Comment: Oh, that's a game changer: the challenge is obviously still valid, but now it has little meaningful interpretation. 

I guess I'll leave it abandoned for future reference of other people not understanding Euclid's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

## Rewrite a number in the Munafo System [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers)

### Output

The [Munafo Alphabetic PT System](https://mrob.com/pub/math/altnum.html#lexi_munafo) (created by Robert Munafo) is a system of concisely writing very large numbers such that ordered values become lexicographically ordered when written. A full description (and some examples) of the system can be found in the link, but here's a series of steps to compute the string *M*(*N*) from a positive real number *N*:

- If *N* < 10, then *M*(*N*) is simply the single digit of *N*, possibly followed by an factional part; that is, `_` followed by any digits after the decimal place of *N*.
- If 10 ≤ *N* < 100, then *M*(*N*) is the letter `a` followed by the two digits of *N*, possibly followed by an factional part.
- If 100 ≤ *N* < 1000, then *M*(*N*) is the letter `b` followed by the three digits of *N*, possibly followed by an factional part.
- If 1000 ≤ *N* < 10 000, then *M*(*N*) is the letter `c` followed by the four digits of *N*, possibly followed by an factional part.
- If 10 000 ≤ *N* < 100 000, then *M*(*N*) is the letter `d` followed by the five digits of *N*, possibly followed by an factional part.
- If 100 000 ≤ *N* < 10<sup>300</sup>, then *M*(*N*) is:

  1. the letter `e`
  2. exactly three digits, representing the exponent of *N*
  3. an underscore `_`
  4. any number of digits, representing the significand of *N* in standardized form.

  More specifically, a string *M*(*N*) = `ex1x2x3_y1y2y3...` represents the value *N* = *y*<sub>1</sub>.*y*<sub>2</sub>*y*<sub>3</sub>... × 10<sup>*x*<sub>1</sub>*x*<sub>2</sub>*x*<sub>3</sub></sup>.
- Finally, if 10<sup>300</sup> ≤ *N*, then to determine *M*(*N*), we must first apply the following recursive process:

  1. Set *T* = 0 and *R* = *N*.
  2. If *R* < 10<sup>300</sup>, then break out of this process.
  3. Otherwise, set *T* = *T* + 1, set *R* = log<sub>10</sub>(*R*), and return to step 2.

  (Effectively, this sets *N* equal to 10<sup>10<sup>…<sup>*R*</sup></sup></sup> with *T* nested exponents.) Now, with our values of *T* and *R*, the value of *M*(*N*) is written as follows:

  1. the letter `e`
  2. the substring *M*(*T*)
  3. an underscore `_`
  4. the substring *M*(*R*).

...and that's the entire system. I apologize if anything I said was unclear or vague; in that case, you should definitely check the link for more detail.

*META*: Is there anything here that can be clarified?

### Operation

As input, your program or function is to take three nonnegative numbers *X*, *Y*, and *Z*. *X* and *Z* are guaranteed to fit in your language's default integer type, and *Y* can fit in the default floating point type. These three values represent the number *N* = 10<sup>…<sup>*Y* × 10<sup>Z</sup></sup></sup>, with *X* initial exponents as before. From here, the challenge is simple: **given *X*, *Y*, and *Z* describing a value *N*, output the Munafo string *M*(*N*).**

### Test cases

*META*: Still figuring these out. Will probably end up using at least a couple from the link. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Formula 1 2016 standings

The Formula 1 2017 season is well underway, but I thought that the final standings could be good idea for a challenge.

The task is to print the standings at the end of 2016 season. This is how the table looks like:

```
1  N Rosberg    385
2  L Hamilton   380
3  D Ricciardo  256
4  S Vettel     212
5  M Verstappen 204
6  K Raikkonen  186
7  S Perez      101
8  V Bottas     85
9  N Hulkenberg 72
10 F Alonso     54
11 F Massa      53
12 C Sainz      46
13 R Grosjean   29
14 D Kvyat      25
15 J Button     21
16 K Magnussen  7
17 F Nasr       2
18 J Palmer     1
19 P Wehrlein   1
20 S Vandoorne  1
21 E Gutierrez  0
22 M Ericsson   0
23 E Ocon       0
24 R Haryanto   0
```

The table is divided into 3 columns: position at the end of season, driver name and points. In each of the columns, the contents can be aligned to left or to right for each column independently. If all columns are aligned to right, the output will look like this:

```
 1    N Rosberg 385
 2   L Hamilton 380
 3  D Ricciardo 256
 4     S Vettel 212
 5 M Verstappen 204
 6  K Raikkonen 186
 7      S Perez 101
 8     V Bottas  85
 9 N Hulkenberg  72
10     F Alonso  54
11      F Massa  53
12      C Sainz  46
13   R Grosjean  29
14      D Kvyat  25
15     J Button  21
16  K Magnussen   7
17       F Nasr   2
18     J Palmer   1
19   P Wehrlein   1
20  S Vandoorne   1
21  E Gutierrez   0
22   M Ericsson   0
23       E Ocon   0
24   R Haryanto   0
```

The columns should be separated exactly by 1 space. Trailing spaces are allowed as well as 1 trailing newline.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) competition - shortest answer wins.

Comment: Thanks for posting in the Sandbox before posting on the main site ;-) In its current state, the challenge seems like it's just about finding the shortest way to encode all the drivers' names and how many points each had at the end of the season. While this may be an interesting challenge for some, many users on the site may find it fairly boring with not much room for real innovation. (You can tag it [tag:kolmogorov-complexity], btw)

Comment: While reading this, I had an idea for a challenge where you take in a driver's last name and output the three-letter abbreviation, but that would be rather boring because that's currently just the first three letters of each name...

Comment: @ETHproductions That could be more interesting with MotoGP or Superbike drivers

Answer (score 0):

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)

**How many times will you have to golf a quine?**

For this challenge, you must create a programme which takes an integer `x` and outputs its source `x` many times.

**Rules**

- This is codegolf, the programme containing the least amount of bytes
  wins.
- If you submit a function, the function must take `x` as  a parameter and either return or print the body of the function `x` many times to STDOUT
- If you submit a lambda, it is not required for you to assign it to a variable
- Standard loophole restrictions apply.
- Empty programmes are forbidden

Comment: There's really no reason not to use code formatting for `x`. The image doesn't even load for me, I had to check the markdown to see what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

## Steal my credit card

recently a lovely man named Boris that I met online sent me a copy of an album that I didn't even know was released yet, the 16kb '.exe' ('EXtremely Excellent-music' apparently) file didn't open, but I did notice that it had managed to make some charges against my credit card, now I'm normally very secure in my banking, I don't write passwords down at all, and I keep my bank details in a '.txt' (Truly eXceedingly proTected) file, so I'm not sure how the hackers managed to get access, to confirm how secure I am:

- I keep a .txt file named 'info.txt' in my documents folder
- There's lots of unimportant information in this
- I store the credit cards in a specific format
- All of my credit cards have the same number of digits in the number and cvv
- the 'Type' of card may be different, but it will always be in the format `Cardtype - MM/YY`
- I don't format anything else in a similar manner, you can assume that this  is the only two lines together.

Example:

```
Visa - 10/18
4024007172038209/571
```

(not a real credit card, i'm not an idiot)

which corresponds to:

```
Type - MM/YY (Expiry date)
CREDIT_CARD_NUM/CVV
```

The format will always match:

```
[a-zA-Z]+ - \d{2}/\d{2}\r?\n\d{16}/\d{3}
```

so it's very difficult to be read by any automatic parsing program.

my insurance doesn't believe me, so I'm here to prove that it's basically impossible, and since we all know programmers are actually just hackers with day jobs, I figured you would all be able to help me.

after adding all of the default Java libraries together and doing some math I believe there's almost no room left for any actual code in the exe file he sent me, so please try and keep the program as short as possible.

The Challenge:

write a program which takes no arguments, and when run will:

- read in a file named 'info.txt' from the same directory the program is run in.
- somewhere in the file, two lines will correspond to the above format
- return only those two lines
- any amount of leading or trailing white-space is allowed.
- you can assume one credit card per file
- you do not need to do any validity checks on the card number etc.

attached is my original info.txt if you want to test against it, but it should work with any credit card number, that way it will be more believable.

[gdrive link to info.txt]

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in each language wins.

Any code, interpreted or compiled, on any system, in any language is valid.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)  [file](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) [text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text)

Comment: It's probably best that the victory condition isn't mentioned in *just* the fluff at the start; I missed it first time I read this. You probably need to confirm what counts as a credit card number or as a CVV. Given the talk about `.exe` files in the fluff, you should also confirm what languages are allowed (it's likely best if you allow any language, even interpreted languages).

Comment: @ais523 added some more clarification there, and a regex to match the two lines.

Comment: Minor correction: the second Z in the regex should be capitalized (should be `[a-zA-Z]` not `[a-zA-z]`)

Comment: @BusinessCat oopsie, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Is the line closed?

Given input consisting of only whitespace characters and `-/\|`, tell if the line created by `-\/|` is closed.

For this challenge, `\` points one character up and to the left, as well as one character down and to the right. `/` points up and to the right, and down and to the left. `|` points one to one character above and below it. `-` points one character to the left and right of it.

```
# means it is being pointed to.

#
 \
  #

  #
 /
#

#-#

#
|
#
```

A line is a bunch of `/\-|` characters that point to each other.

```
     /---\
\    |   |
 \---/   \
```

The characters `-` and `|` cannot validly point to each other. Similarly, `/` and `\` cannot point to each other either.

```
-| = INVALID

|
-  = INVALID

\
 / = INVALID

 /
\  = INVALID
```

A closed line is one where each of its characters validly point to another of its characters.

```
/--\
|  |
\--/ = CLOSED

\--\
|  |
\--/ = NOT CLOSED

---- = NOT CLOSED
```

Your task, as said above, is to write a program that says if a line is closed.

Test cases coming soon.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Comment: Your `-/` connections violate your own specification. I think the clearest specification would be to enumerate all possible legal pairs of connected line segments.

Comment: @ais523 My mistake, I will fix both this and the other.

Answer (score 0):

### Uncompress a permutation

I have a number of permutations, of which this is an example:

```
[0] 1 2 3 15 14 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 5 4 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 35 34 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 25 24 36 37 38 39 [40]
```

(`0` is used for 0-indexed permutations and `40` for 1-indexed permutations.) In order to save space, I want to compress the permutation by reducing each ascending run of consecutive numbers to its first element, giving:

```
0/1 15 14 26 5 4 16 35 34 6 25 24 36
```

This compression method is invertible, because each missing element from the compressed form must follow its predecessor among the integers.

Your challenge is to write a program or function that takes a compressed permutation as input and returns an uncompressed permutation. Your input will consist of an array or list or other reasonable type representing the compressed permutation, plus an integer number of elements in the uncompressed permutation. Examples:

```
[0], 2 -> [0, 1] (0-indexed)
[1], 2 -> [1, 2] (1-indexed)
[6, 2, 0], 8 -> [6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1] (0-indexed)
[7, 4, 1], 9 -> [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3] (1-indexed)
```

In order to make the compression worthwhile I obviously need as short a decompression routine as possible, so this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

Comment: I don't think there's actually a specification of the decompression routine, and the one which I would reverse engineer from the examples at the end is not compatible with the first example.

Comment: I believe the specification is just "for each number that doesn't appear in the compressed permutation, place it to the right of that number minus 1". It might be worth specifying that in the question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The specification is "Create a permutation of the first `n` integers which, when compressed by removing consecutive numbers after the first, results in the input array/list".

Comment: I've made an edit which I think makes that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

## Determine if a relation is an equivalence relation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

(Content to be added.)

### Sandbox

- Inspired by [Is this a function?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118960/is-this-a-function), [Determine if a relation is transitive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100660/determine-if-a-relation-is-transitive)
- Inspires "Determine if a relation is a partial order"

Answer (score 0):

## Output the Balmer Series

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

### Challenge

Write a program which outputs the following image (note, it is an svg):

[image]

It is the emission spectrum of hydrogen, caused by the Balmer series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#5

Your program must not read the image from the internet or a local file.

The image may be to an image file or a graphics window. If not a vector, the image sides must be greater than 400 pixels.

Your image must have the same colours and same ratios of spacing between each line.

### Winning

Shortest code wins.

Comment: What does it mean to output the image "*exactly*"? It's obviously not pixel-for-pixel for two reasons: firstly, because the image isn't raster, and secondly, because the spec allows for variation in image size.

Answer (score 0):

### An implementation of a game called Nomic [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

[Nomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomic) is a game where you can change the rules. Humans are biased judges though, so let's have a computer run the rules! (Note that there are many variations of Nomic. Below is just one example.) Since you're minimalists, you want the original ruleset to be as short as possible.

Your program first accepts as input a list of players. You must be able to accept any list of 2 to 16 unique alphanumeric usernames (you may assume that the list of players names are valid according to this criteria).

Next print `The name of this game is nomic. The goal is to get the last line of output of this program to be "[username] is the winner!", where [username] is your username.`

Now, for each player print `[username], do you want to propose a revision to the rules? If so, type the revised code below:` where `[username]` is the player's username. (This input must be able to accept multiple lines.) If the input is empty, proceed to the next player.

If not, for each player print `[username], do you want to accept or reject this change to the rules?(y/n)`, where `[username]` is the player's username. (You may assume input to this will either be `y` or `n`.) If the number of `y`s are more than the number of `n`s, execute it (in the language you are writing the implemenation). If not, proceed with the next player.

If the code executes without an error, the program ends. If not print `The ruleset proposed by [username] has crashed. The game will proceed with the original ruleset.` where `[username]` is the players username. Then proceed to the next player after them.

Note: After all the players have either proposed a rule or passed, start with the first player again.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest Nomic implementation wins! (You get 0 characters off your score if you show an example game you played with your friends. This bonus is doubled if all the revised rulesets are golfed.)

Comment: You say a computer has to "run the rules", so is each rule typed by a user an executable piece of code? Basically, your description of what the implementation needs to look like is extremely vague. Be specific.

Comment: Having long hardcoded strings in a challenge is generally a bad idea unless it's a [tag:compression] challenge, as the question will be mostly about compressing the strings rather than about what it's meant to be about. One possibility is to not count the strings against the byte count if they appear literally in the code.

Comment: @mbomb007 the rule should be a piece of executable code. If it isn't, the program announces the error.

Comment: @ais523 that's a little tricky since it involves a little bit of string splicing. Is there a way around that, or should I just shorten them?

Comment: Probably best at this point to just use codes for the various situations, e.g. using just `V` to request someone to vote.

Answer (score 0):

## Compute Area of Convex Hull of Roots of Polynomial

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[polynomial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomial)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given a nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients, find the area of the convex hull of the complex roots of the polynomial.

#### Details

The polynomial can be given in any reasonable format, e.g. as a list of coefficients. The area must be correct to 4 significant figures. You can assume that the degree of the polynomial is no larger than 8, and that the coefficients are less than `8^8 = 16777216`, (and by Rouché's theorem the roots have therefore an absolute value of less than `8^8 + 1`).

#### Example

The polynomial `x^4 - 1`  has the roots `{1,-1,i,-i}` which form the vertices of their convex hull, which is a square of sidelength `sqrt(2)` so the total area is `2`.

The polynomial `x^5 - x` has the roots `{1,-1,i,-i,0}`. But the convex hull is again given by the vertices points `{1,-1,i,-i}`.

The constant polynomial `1` has no roots, and therefore the convex hull of its roots is empty.

The polynomial `x^2 - 1` has the roots `{1,-1}`, so their convex hull is just a line segment, which has no area.

In the following the polynomials are given as a list of coefficient of the monomials in descending degree. (i.e. the constant comes last)

```
[1,2,3,4,1] 2.0382
[1,2,3,4,5] 3.5830
[1,-1,1,-1] 1.0000
[a,b] 0 (where a != 0 and b arbitrary)
```

Comment: For what range of inputs must the area be correct to 4s.f.?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that, thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

## Hidden Strings

*This is real rough, I just wanted to get the idea down.*

The `strings` utility that comes on many GNU/Linux distros finds the strings in executables and lists them. The goal of this challenge is to write a program that has a null-terminated string in the compiled executable (compiled languages only, sorry) but that string does not appear in the source. The scoring is the ratio of the length of the hidden string to the size of your source code.

The following constraints apply:

The string must be entirely dictionary words from `todo` dictionary with length greater than 2 concatenated together without spaces and without punctuation. If `xyz` and `abc` are words in the dictionary, the following is a valid string: `xyzabcxyzabc`, but the following is not `xyabcz` (assuming that it is not a concatenation of other strings in the dictionary). For those of you who care, if `E` is the dictionary of words of length greater than 2, then strings must be in `E*` where `*` is the Kleene star.

"Hidden" means that the string and its substrings may not appear as strings or characters in your source. *This definition needs a bunch of work*.

*This challenge was supposed to be something like "Hey, how would you hide a funny string so that it doesn't appear obviously in the source, but does appear when someone looks at the executable". I welcome all suggestions because as I have it currently stated, I think there are a lot of problems.*

Comment: I'm guessing that a minimal C program already contains a certain number of strings in the binary? Does this come down to creative you get with compiler flags, asking it to statically link as many libraries as possible?

Comment: I suggest specifying a *particular* string that has to be hidden, in order to prevent solutions based on the default behaviour of the toolchain. (This would also simplify the question somewhat) Additionally, that string should probably be banned from thing like the filename and the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

## Write a TIO bot

Write a program/function which:

1. Takes three strings *Language*, *Code*, and *Input*
2. Do one of the following:

   1. Assume access to a browser open on `https://tio.run/nexus/`; click `[data-id="`*Language*`"`
3. Go to `https://tio.run/nexus/`*Language*`/`
4. Enters *Code* in the `<textarea id="code">`
5. Enters *Input* in the `<textarea id="input">`
6. Clicks the `<span id="run">`
7. Waits for any of these things to happen:

   1. `<textarea class="output">` changes
   2. `<textarea id="debug">` changes
   3. 60 seconds pass
8. Returns/prints the content of `<textarea class="output">`

Alternatively, you may use the TIO API.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

Comment: I'd allow people to use the API, instead of using the HTML.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Added. But good luck finding out what it is.

Comment: The problem with the API is that it's bound to change until it becomes stable. Incidentally, this is why I'm not documenting it at this point, as nobody *should* use it while it's still in flux.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert ambiguous dates to "the correct way" (YYYY-MM-DD)

A problem I run into often with spreadsheets of data is dealing with dates of unknown ordering.

[image: XKCD says it best]

Your task is to take a series of dates that are in one of the following three formats, and output them as YYYY-MM-DD:

- `DD/MM/YYYY`
- `MM/DD/YYYY`
- `YYYY-MM-DD`

No other date formats are acceptable.

Since many dates are ambiguous, you must read all the dates to determine whether the set is MM/DD or DD/MM before outputting anything.

Your program must also detect the following error conditions and return an error code instead (with no other output):

- `-1`: Unable to determine date ordering. (All dates provided could be DD/MM or MM/DD)
- `-2`: Inconsistent date ordering. (There are dates provided that are definitely DD/MM and others that are definitely MM/DD, within the same set).
- `-3`: Bad data. (There are things included that are not valid dates, as defined above, including things like 31/04/2017 and 12/1/1980).

For the purposes of this challenge, February always has 28 days, April, June, September and November have 30 days, and all others have 31 days. All years, from 0001 to 9999 are equivalent.

### Sample input/output

```
['11/05/1988','12/12/1960'] => -1
['15/05/1988','03/18/2001'] => -2
['15/05/1988','31/06/1989'] => -3
['15/05/1988','2014-02-02', '18/03/2001'] => ['1988-05-15','2014-02-02', '2001-03-18']
['05/15/1988','03/18/2001'] => ['1988-05-15','2001-03-18']
```

### I/O

You can receive data in whatever way is normal for your language (line-separated stdin, array of strings, whatever). You may assume that the data you receive is of the correct type (ie, your array won't contain integers, nulls etc), but may contain empty strings.

If outputting to standard output, errors can be sent to stderr, or as program termination code. If implementing a function, you can return an integer instead of an array, throw an error, or whatever seems natural.

### Scoring

The score for your program is `L - 2Y + 20D` where:

- `L` is the length of your code, in bytes
- `Y` is 2017 minus the year in which the first version of the language you're using was published.
- `D` is the number of times the letters 'date', in any case, appear consecutively in your code.

For the purpose of `Y`, all versions of Lisp are 59, C is 39, C++ is 32, all EcmaScripts are 20 etc. Languages are considered the same if they have the same name (other than the version number). (No cheating by using some golf language that happens to be called C though.)

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) *(what else?)*

Comment: I think your scoring mechanism isn't going to work. It's probably best you stick to plain old shortest code.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: [Possible dup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33033/has-my-milk-expired)

Comment: @SteveBennett If your score decreases by 20 each time 'date' is in the code, then if someone fits an infinite amount of 'date' into a comment, they win.

Comment: It increases, not decreases...?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma They're both in the same ballpark but a lot of differences, including fundamental task (reformatting vs outputting a single probability), input formats (strict mm/dd/yyyy vs m-d-yy) etc.

Answer (score 0):

### **Be the Richest Mammut!**

### The Game

This game is an adaptation of a board game called Mammut, and basically an optimization problem.

Each match contains five players and five rounds, in which every player participates. Every round starts with a bunch of tiles being flipped at random on one of their sides, and put in the middle stack
The tile composition will be fixed, but has not been completely decided yet There will be 30-35 of them, and each of them will have two different sides, with exactly 15 different types of tiles, and about half of those only having one single instance available.
A random player is chosen as the starting player for the first round, and performance will decide the starter for the following four rounds.
In order, each player that doesn't own any tiles will take an action, and this will keep going on until every player has at least one tile.
The actions available are:

1. Take an arbitrary number of tiles from the middle stack.
2. Take all of the tiles owned by another player, and put one of them back in the middle stack.

Obviously, you can take the entire middle stack, but if there is at least one other player without tiles and you take too many, he will most likely steal your tiles right after.

### Scoring

Every player starts with 10 points, and if they end a scoring phase under zero, they will be given enough free points to go back to zero.

When everyone has tiles, the round is over, and we move on to scoring that round. Since this is played by bots and not humans, an infinite loop is possible, so after 1000 actions, the round will be stopped by force, and the players participating in the infinite loop who ended up empty ended will naturally end this round with a terrible score.

Scoring happens all at once, and you get (or lose) points according to the tiles you have, and the tiles the other players have. When scoring is done, we move on to the next round, or declare the winner if that was the fifth round.

### The Tiles

There are different types of tiles, and you job is basically to find the best balance between them while not having enough to make your stack worth stealing.

- Fire | The player who has the fewest fire tiles loses 5 points
- Meat | The three players owning the most meat tiles get 8, 5 and 2 points respectively
- Fur | Every fur tile gives you onw "fur point". During every round after the first, the player with the most fur points plays first. At the end of each round, the player with the most fur tiles gets the round number in points (1-5), while the one who has the least loses the round number in points.
- Ivory Tile | Every Ivory tile gives you two points.
- Axe Tile | (This one should be discussed) Every axe tile gives you one point, and every axe Tile obtained in the last round is Worth 3 points
- Animal Tiles | There are 7 different animals (Bat, Opossum, Bunny, Buffalo, Squirrel, Beaver and Duck), and only one of each in the game. When you end the round with one, you "obtain" this animal, and getting the same one again will do nothing. At the end of the game, depending on the number of animals you have obtained, you get points. (0: 0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:4, 4:9, 5:15, 6:22, 7:30)
- Mystery Tile | If you get a mystery tile, it will be turned around to reveal its other side during the scoring phase. The other side can't be another mystery tile or an animal tile.
- Tie-Breaker Tile | This tile serves as a tie breaker. One side is the "clockwise" side, and the other side is the "counter-clockwise", so every round will contain a tie-breaker tile. During any and all ties during scoring, the tie-breaker tile decides who wins or loses.

### Clockwise?

At the start of the game, every player will be given a random ID between 1 and 5. The player with ID 1 will start the game. Then, for the following rounds, the most fur points decides who starts, and the ID decides the order. Example: ID 3 has the most furs, then the order will be [3, 4, 5, 1, 2].

This is considered "clockwise". The counter-clockwise order would be [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]. This is important, because when dealing with ties, the tie-breaker tile takes the order into account.

If player 4 owns the clockwise tie-breaker tiles, and has 3 meats. Player 1 and 2 also have three meats. The first, second and third place in meat then go to players ID 4, 1 and 2 respectively. If everyone has 3 fires, except player 3 and 5 who have 1, then player 3 is the one to lose points. Having the tie-breaker tiles means you are first in the tie-breaking order, and that tile's visible side decide the rest of the order.

### Challenge specifications

You must make a C# class that inherits from a "Player" class. You must also override the method

```
List<int> ChooseTiles(Dictionary<int, List<Tile>> otherPlayers, List<Tile> center)
```

This method takes a dictionary of player IDs and List of tiles (could be empty), that are each player's tiles at the moment, plus a list of tiles in the middle. You must return a list of integer, which are the IDs of the tiles you want. If you try to get tiles illegally (not following the instructions for taking an action, which are either any number of tiles from the middle or all tiles except one from a player), you will be asked to choose one more time, and if you fail to follow the rules, you will be counted as "attempting to cheat" and removed from the "playing" pool during this round, so you will get scored for an empty hand. The same thing goes for throwing exceptions and infinite loops (Execution lasting more than 5 seconds). You are given one more chance then given an empty hadn for that round.

Here is the class Player you will be inheriting from:

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID;
    public int currentPoints;
    public int currentFurs;
    public List<Tile> currentTiles;
    public List<TileType> animalsGotten;

    public Player(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        currentPoints = 10;
        currentFurs = 0;
        currentTiles = new List<Tile>();
        animauxGotten = new List<TileType>();
    }

    public virtual List<int> ChooseTiles(Dictionary<int, List<Tile>> otherPlayers, List<Tile> center)
    {
        throw new Exception("Fake players don't get to play!");
    }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "Player";
    }
}
```

You should also override the GetName() function, but it is not required.
You are allowed to create as many private functions or attributes as you want to store data during a game, but each match will create a new instance of your player.

### The Tournament

tournament will be played in a round-robin fashion. You are not garanteed a match with every single combination of four opponents available, but you are garanteed at least one match in common with every other bot, and everyone will play the same number of matches. You will also not play twice with the same 5 players. The total number of matches will depend on the number of participants.
For each match, the first player will get 5 points, and the others will get respectively 3, 2, 1 and zero points depending on their points earned during the match. Furthermore, and ties in points will not be resolved, and the points of the occupied positions split between tied players. This means that if the points are (40, 37, 37, 37, 35), the points are (5, 2, 2, 2, 0)

Comment: People usually don't like KotH challenges that are restricted to one language. See some other KotH challenges for ways to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large collection of fine art.  My toddler is learning to use scissors and glue; lately she has started playing with my art collection.  Fortunately she is really quite good with the scissors and cuts things up into perfect squares.  She then uses glue to randomly tile the cut-up squares back into a new piece of art.  For example, she reinterpreted my *Mona Lisa* ([which wikipedia kindly hosts for me](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Mona_Lisa.PNG/685px-Mona_Lisa.PNG)) as follows:

[image]

The following python script simulates what my toddler has done:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import random
from PIL import Image

origname = sys.argv[1]

im = Image.open(origname)
width, height = im.size
width = (int(width + 99) / 100) * 100
height = (int(height + 99) / 100) * 100

im = im.crop((0, 0, width, height))

im2 = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), "black")

blocks = []
for x in range(width / 100):
    for y in range(height / 100):
        blocks.append(im.crop((x * 100, y * 100, (x + 1) * 100, (y + 1) * 100)))

random.shuffle(blocks)



im2.save("shuf" + origname)
```

<sub>Please excuse python skills - I'm still learning, but was happy to see how quick and easy it was to write this script.  Polite code-reviews will be graciously accepted ;-)</sub>

It does the following:

- loads the image whose file name was given as a command-line parameter
- pads that image with black pixels such that the width and height are exactly divisible by 100
- divides the image into 100x100 pixel blocks
- randomly shuffles the blocks
- reassembles the randomly arranged blocks back into a new image with the same size attributes as the (padded) original
- saves the new image using the original filename prefixed with `shuf`

---

Your task is to write a program that takes the output of this script, analyses the edges of each 100x100 block and reassembles them back to the original picture.

#### Input:

- an image filename.  This may be passed at the commandline, via STDIN or even hard-coded, whichever is most convenient.

#### Output:

- either output the a singular rearranged image to a differnent file, or display the singular rearranged output to the screen.

Input and output specs are intended to be lenient here, as filename-parsing is a non-goal of this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question.

#### Other rules

- The program must be able to correctly reassemble any random arrangement of the wikipedia Mona Lisa by the python script.  Hard-coding of block transformations of the example image above is strictly *not* allowed.
- It is understood that for some degenerate cases (e.g. chequerboard of 100x100) blocks it is impossible to correctly rearrange the image.  In those cases it is acceptable to produce incorrect/undefined output.  However I think in general for photo images and almost all "famous" artworks, reassembly should be possible.  Works by [Mark Rothko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Rothko) are a possible exception.
- Common image manipulation libraries may be used (e.g. Python's PIL), but any APIs expressly designed for this purpose are strictly banned.
- [Standard “loopholes” which are no longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny)

---

Now my toddler got a hold of [*The Scream*](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f4/The_Scream.jpg/608px-The_Scream.jpg).  This is the result that needs to be fixed:

[image]

## Special thanks to Digital Trauma!

He wrote the original challenge and gave it up original post [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture)

## META:

I need to update the images and the script to not have rotations and to not have black bars. Any ideas?

Comment: The way to make this objective is to have a large list of images (like 50 or so), and require 100% accuracy.  You should also reserve the right to regenerate the test cases if anybody is hardcoding the input.

Comment: Please credit [the question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38534/stitch-a-picture) that the inspiration (*or direct copy ?!?*) came from.  Also, please note the comments to that question very carefully.  In its current form, there significant problems (up to and including impossible to get 100% accuracy).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Sorry. I forgot to add that. It was a copy with edits based on you giving it up to gift exchange

Comment: Somebody suggested using lossless image formats, which would help a lot in terms of edges now being exact matches.  That might be less interesting though.  Nathan suggested a large list of images, which could give it the test-battery tag perhaps?  My two suggestions I believe are at odds.

Answer (score 0):

## Extension of MIME-Type

Your task, given this [list of extension and MIME-types](https://pastebin.com/CUv4Bfdi), is to choose exactly ***20*** of them and create a program that takes in either `e`, the extension, or `m`, the MIME-Type, and outputs its counterpart.

---

Example (if my set was [`.pdf`, `.doc`]):

**Cases to handle:**

```
f('.pdf') = application/pdf
f('application/pdf') = .pdf
f('application/msword') = .doc
f('.doc') = application/msword
```

**Cases you don't have to touch:**

```
f('Nonsense') = [Error, null, false, whatever]
```

## I & O

- Input will be a single string, so will output.
- You must handle 20 mime-type combinations and mention which ones you are handling.
- Trailing spaces and newlines are fine.
- Extensions always include the preceding period.
- When choosing a long extension like `.cryptocode`, if you return the MIME-type of `.cryptocode` for an input of `.cry` it will be considered an invalid submission, remember this.

## Winning

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorolofvlfoao-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorolofvlfoao-complexity), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: [tag:kolmogorolofvlfoao-complexity]???

Comment: Be sure to include the list in the question itself when you post this on main. We want questions to be self-contained.

Comment: "When choosing a long extension like .cryptocode, if you return the MIME-type of .cryptocode for an input of .cry it will be considered an invalid submission, remember this." - why? Do I _have_ to detect if the input is one of my set? This will reduce my compression ratio significantly.

Comment: @JanDvorak it's too big for posting here, and if pastebin goes does a lot of the internet would lose a lot of data.

Comment: @programmer5000 you can post it if you want.

Comment: Concerning the "exactly 20" requirement: Are we allowed to output anything we want if fed something not in that 20 or does it need to output a falsey value? The addition of the word "whatever" added confusion for me.

Comment: @programmer5000 [Tab-separated version](https://pastebin.com/N1Z9FLKr) for OP's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

### Make some arrays

A recent post on The Daily WTF concerned the creation of four two-dimensional arrays of height `n`. Please write a function to create these arrays for me. Here is an example for `n=4`:

```
[[1] [[1 0 0] [[0] [[0 0 0]
 [0]  [0 1 0]  [0]  [1 0 0]
 [0]  [0 0 1]  [0]  [0 1 0]
 [0]] [0 0 0]] [1]] [0 0 1]]
```

Rules:

- All four arrays must be two-dimensional. Arrays which have been flattened in any way are not acceptable.
- You can write separate functions for each array, in which case your score is the total of the scores for each function.
- Your functions can call each other, provided you include the name in your score. Otherwise unnamed functions are acceptable.
- Rather than returning the array(s), you can be passed them in as an input parameter (e.g. using `int**` in C).
- If your language has a builtin for inputting arbitrary data structures, then you can write a full program that outputs using the input format that the builtin would recognise.
- Alternatively, you can write a full program that outputs source code for the arrays in your language.
- All standard loopholes are banned.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest function wins.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if you can reconstruct these four arrays if you just evaluate that code block as is. If so, that might be a fun challenge too. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Parse a 4-dimensional array

A 2D array is fairly easy to represent in ASCII art, something like this:

```
1  2
6 24
```

One approach for a 3D array is to have a number of 2D arrays, with an extra blank line between each array:

```
1  2
6 24

1  2
4  8
```

Things get a little more complicated for 4D arrays though. The best you can do is to arrange a number of 3D arrays side-by-side, but with at least two spaces between each array:

```
1  2   1  2
6 24   3  4

1  2   1  4
4  8  27 64
```

So that I don't have to ban full programs, the challenge will be to input 4 (numeric) indices along with a 4D array which will be as some sort of string in the above format, and output the (numeric) 4D array element at those indices. For example, if the 1-indexed indices were 1, 2, 1, 2 then the result would be 4. Rules:

- You must at a minimum support integers from 0 to 255, written in decimal.
- The array will not be ragged, but you will not be given the size of the array. Any of the dimensions may be 1, so `0 0 0 0 0` is a valid input in 0-based indexing.
- Numbers in the array will be consistently justified (please state whether you support left or right, or decimal justification if you support floating-point numbers), but the output must not contain any whitespace except for an optional trailing newline.
- You may choose 0 or 1-based indexing.
- You can choose row-major format instead of column-major format, as long as both outer and inner arrays have the same format. The first two indices will however always refer to the outer array and the last two indices to the inner array indexed by the first two indices.
- You can assume that the indices will always be valid.
- All standard loopholes are banned.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function wins.

Comment: `some sort of string in the above format` so no JSON?

Comment: @StephenS Correct, you won't be given an actual array, you'll be given an ASCII-art printout of the array.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Generating strings of Rs and spaces

If a task is to make a string of 16 characters using 2 different characters, it can be done in 2^16=65536 ways. Let's generate them all!

Write a program or function which takes a number in range [0, 65535] as input and outputs a string of 16 characters consisting of `R` and   (space). One number corresponds to one string and must generate the same string each time the code is run.

### Example

Suppose that a program/function takes a binary representation of the number and replaces zeros with spaces and ones with Rs to make the string. The conversion from input to output will look as follows:

```
0     -> "                "
1     -> "               R"
2     -> "              R "
3     -> "              RR"
...
65532 -> "RRRRRRRRRRRRRR  "
65533 -> "RRRRRRRRRRRRRR R"
65534 -> "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR "
65535 -> "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"
```

### Sandbox notes

- This challenge probably needs a better name. If you have an idea, please mention it.
- I know that this challenge will be boring if making the string from binary representation is the shortest way in all languages. I hope that this isn't the case.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that making it from the binary representation would not be the shortest way is if there's a shorter way with a Cartesian product built-in, but that's still boring.

Answer (score 0):

## Boxes

N boxes are lined up in a sequence (1 ≤ N ≤ 20).
You have A red balls and B blue balls (0 ≤ A ≤ 15, 0 ≤ B ≤ 15).
The red balls (and the blue ones) are exactly the same.
You can place the balls in the boxes.
It is allowed to put in a box, balls of the two kinds, or only from one kind.
You can also leave some of the boxes empty.
It's not necessary to place all the balls in the boxes.

### challenge!

Write a program, which finds the number of different ways to place the balls in the boxes in the described way.

#### Input

Input contains one line with three integers N, A and B separated by space.

#### Output

The result of your program must be an integer written on the only line of output.

#### Sample I/O

input

```
2 1 1
```

output

```
9
```

Comment: This is just "Calculate the product of two binomial coefficients", and is therefore a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1744/194

Answer (score 0):

## Split the atom

**Input**: 0 <= X <= 2³² - 1

**Output**: List of numbers in decimal, after recursive splitting in binary format.

**Explanation**:

*Example 1:*

`Input:` `255`

Current `Output` is `255`.

Binary representation of `255` is `1111 1111`. Splitting it, we get `1111` and `1111`, which in decimal are `15` and `15`.

Continuing the `Output`, we will have `255 15 15`.

Now the numbers `15` and `15` will serve as inputs and these numbers are to be split.

Continuing the `Output`, we will have `255 15 15 3 3 3 3`.

Continuing the logic, final `Output` will be `255 15 15 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` . And since `1` can no longer be split, the output stops.

*Example 2:*

`Input:` `225`

Current `Output` is `225`.

Binary representation of `225` is `1110 0001`. Splitting it, we get `1110` and `0001`, which in decimal are `14` and `1`.

Continuing the `Output`, we will have `225 14 1`.

Now the numbers `14` and `1` will serve as inputs and these numbers are to be split.

Since `1` is no longer split-able,  the `Output` will be `225 14 1 3 2`.

Final `Output` will be `225 14 1 3 2 1 1 1 0`.

*Example 3:*

`Input: 32`

`Output: 32 4 0 1 0`.

---

**Conditions**:

1. If the number of binary digits are odd, the first number will have one fewer binary digit than the next one. Example, `20 (10100)` will be split as `10` and `100`, with decimal output being `2` and `4`.
2. Standard loophole rules apply.
3. `0`s and `1`s do not propagate further.
4. Program crashing for trying to display too many numbers is a valid exit condition.

Comment: Surely you reversed the inequality signs.

Comment: `s/Splitting it/Splitting it in half/`

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, yes I did :D

Comment: @trichoplax I updated the conditions. Is that clearer?

Comment: @trichoplax I hope 3 examples clears everything up.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of an earlier question, but I haven't found it by searching for *binary split*. Perhaps someone else will be able to find it.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc yes that clears up the treatment of the zeroes

Answer (score 0):

## Simplify ordinal expression

WIP.

Answer (score 0):

## Pi - The Movie!

## Introduction

So we've had the musical version [The Sound of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107180/play-the-sound-of-pi), now its time for the movie.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to write a full program or function that outputs an animated version of pi to 100 decimal places.

For your convenience, here's Pi to 100 decimal places

```
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

## Input and Output

Input: No input required

Output: A single gif file

## Rules

- Only one digit or decimal point should be shown at a time
- Each digit or decimal point should be shown for for between 0.25 and 1.5 seconds (your choice).
- The font should be clearly visible (different colour to background)
- The characters should be at least 100 pixels high and have at least a 1 pixel boarder
- You can use built in values of pi as long as they're correct to 100 dp
- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is the time constraint realistic?
- What tags should I use?

Comment: I'd VTC this as "too broad".

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer could you explain why? a VTC on its own doesn't help me improve it :)

Comment: Basically there are many ways you could make a "video file" (file formats), the font size could be invisibly small, the background color may be the same as the foreground color, digits might not fully appear (i.e. be cut) etc.

Comment: i think a gif with fixed size would be better

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer added size and colour constraints. I've already specified the format should suitable for vlc or wmp.

Comment: @Notts90 saying it's suitable for vlc or wmp does not say much, something that runs in my vlc may not run in yours (installed codecs and stuff)

Comment: I'll go with the gif option then!

Answer (score 0):

## Program Equilibrium Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma Tournament

This is an iterated prisoners dilemma tournament. You are to make a bot that plays the prisoners dilemma against the other contestants, but with a twist- you can perfectly simulate your opponent!

### Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma

The [prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma) is
a two-player game in which players can choose to either "Cooperate" or "Defect"
against their opponent.  The payoff matrix for the prisoner's dilemma looks
like this:

```
                           Player 2
                       C              D

                 ------------------------------
                |              |               |
            C   |    (3, 3)    |    (0, 5)     |
                |              |               |
Player 1        |------------------------------|
                |              |               |
            D   |    (5, 0)    |    (1, 1)     |
                |              |               |
                 ------------------------------
```

In the iterated prisoner's dilemma, multiple rounds are played in succession,
and players can use their knowledge of the previous rounds when making a
decision.

### The twist

Bots are also allowed to run their opponent and examine the output before
making a move. This allows for significantly more complex strategies in which
bots can simulate their opponents to determine if it is safe to cooperate with
them, as well as attempt to exploit less sophisticated players.

### Simulation

There will be a program available in the path called `simulate` that you can use to simulate what your opponent would do against you

Usage:

```
simulate [instruction to your own bot] [fake history to the opponent]
```

Example:

```
simulate cooperate 00 10 01 11 01 10
```

All arguments are optional, and you may also use underscore `_` for no argument. If you do not explicitly state the history, the real history will be used.

Example output from the `simulate` program:

```
01
```

The first number is you, the second is your opponent. `0` means defect, `1` means cooperate.

### The instruction

It wouldn't be much use to simulate what your opponent would do against you, because he'd probably simulate you right back, and then you'd be stuck in an infinite loop.
The instruction is your way to simulate what the opponent would do against another agent. You could for instance have a cooperate instruction that causes your bot to cooperate mindlessly, to see what the opponent would do if you were to cooperate.

### Input

Your program will be given the following input at the beginning of each round:

```
Instruction (if any)
Your score
Your opponents score
Current round number
Complete history of past interactions with this bot. Space separated: the first number is you, the second is your opponent
```

Example:

```
cooperative
5
2
3
00 10
```

### Output

`0` for defect or `1` for cooperate, with any number of leading characters. Trailing characters (including 0 or 1's) will be ignored.

Example:

```
1
```

### The tournament

The tournament will be round-robin elimination: Each bot will play one match against all other bots, where a match consists of 100 rounds of the prisoner's dilemma. At the end of the round-robin round, the lower-scoring half of the tournament pool will be eliminated. This process will be repeated until only one bot remains, or there is a tie.

### Rules

- Your program has to run on Linux. Please provide a brief description of how to run your program if possible
- Your program has to give an answer within 5 seconds. Failing to do so will be interpreted as defect.
- Your program may not perform multiple simulations at the same time
- You may only enter a single bot, this is to prevent people from entering multiple bots that cooperate
- You may not read or write any files. If this is required by your language, please state so in your answer.
- You may not in any way store state between rounds. This is to prevent bots from figuring out whether they are being simulated.
- If you exploit another loophole to figure out whether you are being simulated, you will be disqualified. Guessing (or strategical testing) is obviously allowed

### About the host computer

```
Arch Linux 4.10.13-1
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz, 4 cores
16 GB RAM
I will disconnect from the internet while running the tournament
```

### Disclosure

I got the idea as well as some of the text from [this](https://github.com/pdtournament/pdtournament/blob/master/README.md) Github repository.
I have not directly asked the author for permission to use the challenge, but he said that "if you want to run this tournament on your own, you are more than welcome to" in a [blogpost](http://lesswrong.com/r/lesswrong/lw/l16/2014_iterated_prisoners_dilemma_tournament_results/).

## Leaderboard

I will update this periodically whenever new bots enter.

## Meta

How do I best discourage/prevent players from intentionally using every bit of their time limit to sabotage other players trying to simulate them?
I am thinking random time limits and/or penalties

Comment: Have you ever run a KotH? If not, I think you are about to learn how incredibly slow a round can be even if the programs have very simple logic. With the `simulate` instruction I anticipate taking hours to run a single round.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's good advice; I might not want to run this on my main computer

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Wardialing was a very interesting way to try to hack people back in the '80s and '90s. When everyone used dial-up, people would dial huge amounts of numbers to search for BBS's, computers, or fax machines. If it was answered by a human or answering machine, it hung up and forgot the number. If it was answered by a modem or a fax machine, it would make note of the number.

## Challenge

Your job is to make a URL wardialer. Something that tests and checks if it's a valid website from one letter of the alphabet.

## Constraints

- Program must take user input. This input has to be a letter of the alphabet, no numbers. Just one letter of the alphabet and form multiple URLs that start with the letter.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- You must make 8 URLs from 1 letter, and test to see if it is a valid site.
- If you hit an error (not a response code), instead of leaving it blank, go ahead and return a 404
- If you hit a redirect (3xx), return a 200 instead.
- You may output the results in any reasonable format, as long as it includes the website name, status codes for all the websites and the redirects
- This is Code Golf, so shortest amount of bytes wins.

## What counts as a URL for this challenge?

http://{domain-name}.{com or net or org}

For this challenge, the domain name is should only be 4 letters long, no more, no less.

## What should I test?

For each 4 letter domain name, test it against three top-level domains (.com, .net, .org). Record all the response codes from each URL, remember from the constraints that any (3xx) should return 200 and be recorded as a redirect in the output and any error getting to the website should result in a 404.

## Input

> a

## Output

```
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| Website | .com | .net | .org | Redirects? |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| ajoe    | 200  | 200  | 200  | .com, .net |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| aqiz    | 200  | 404  | 404  | no         |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| amnx    | 200  | 503  | 404  | .com       |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| abcd    | 200  | 404  | 200  | .com       |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| ajmx    | 200  | 503  | 404  | no         |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| aole    | 200  | 200  | 200  | .com       |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| apop    | 404  | 200  | 200  | .net       |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
| akkk    | 200  | 200  | 200  | .com       |
+---------+------+------+------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't like the formatting aspect; it adds a whole unnecessary layer to the meat of challenge. I also don't like the fact that you have to go through `.com`, `.net`, and `.org` for the same reason. But I do like the concept, and I think if you stay closer to the actual challenge ("generate a few websites and check if they exist") it could be well-received on main.

Comment: but the formatting looks sooooo good

Comment: Well then, maybe you should post a challenge idea to format a table like that ;-) I think we may have already had that challenge though.

Comment: ehhh, nah. what should i replace it with

Comment: I'd allow users to output in any reasonable format they like: an array of arrays, a newline-separated string, etc. A table like that would still be allowed, though it probably wouldn't be the shortest.

Comment: URLs for websites all start with the letter `h`. If you want to make an argument about relative URLs, I will concede that they can also start with the non-letter `/`. But abusing a clearly defined term like URL to the extent to which it's abused in this draft only serves to confuse people. The task is: given an input of one letter of the alphabet, generate 8 alphabetic *labels*, from each of those labels to generate three *domain names*, and for each of those names test the response code of the *URL* `http://{name}/`

Comment: Also, in "*Something has more than 4 letters in it*", *more than* is exclusive, so this is not consistent with the example.

Comment: There. I think this edit helps @PeterTaylor

Answer (score 0):

## Fill to the line!

Given input consisting of the characters `_`,  , and newline, fill the empty space up to the line!

**Example:**

I will use `#` as the filler character in the example.

```
1. Input
        
        
________
        
        
        
2. Fill up to the line, but not above.
        
        
________
########
########
########
```

- You may assume that the input either is rectangular (is padded), or consists only of the line and newlines.
- You may assume that there is only one straight, unbroken line.
- The whitespace above the line is part of the input. Do not fill above the line.

**Test cases:**

```
"
Input
"
"
Output
"
**********

"
    
    
    
----
    
    
    
    
"
"
    
    
    
----
####
####
####
####
"

**********

"
        
        
________
        
        
        
"
"
        
        
________
########
########
########
"
```

Comment: is the input guaranteed to be rectangular? will the _ be on one line

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I will edit to clarify.

Comment: If its padded its very trivial to just replace all the spaces with #

Comment: @Notts90 Not all the spaces, only the ones below the line.

Comment: Ah ok, might want to make it clearer the bit above the line are included in the input.

Answer (score 0):

## 21 = (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9) - (1 + 3)

***Sandbox question**:

Is this different enough from [the original challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120487/58563)?*

---

#### Background

- This is a [sequel to my previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120487/58563), but this time with a slightly more interesting practical application (the factorization of the input).
- It is based on *1)* the fact that any odd integer ***n*** can be expressed as the difference of two squares ***a² - b²*** and *2)* the well known formula:

  [image: formula]

#### The task

You're given a positive odd integer ***n***. Your task is to determine how many iterations of the following algorithm need to be processed to reach ***n***.

- Initialization: find the highest integer ***k*** such that ***k² ≤ n***. Build the list ***L = [ 1, 3, 5, ..., 2k-1 ]***.
- Iteration:

  - Step #1: If the sum of the terms of ***L*** equals ***n***, stop here.
  - Step #2: Increment ***k*** and append ***2k-1*** to ***L***.
  - Step #3: While the sum of the terms of ***L*** is greater than ***n***, remove the first term from the list. Go on with step #1.

All iterations (either full or partial) must be counted. In other words, you must return the number of times step #1 was executed.

#### Example #1

This is a trivial example for the perfect square ***n = 9***:

- Initialization: ***k = 3*** because ***3² ≤ 9 < 4²***, which leads to ***L = [ 1, 3, 5 ]***.
- Step #1: ***1 + 3 + 5 = 9***. We're done.

We went through one iteration. So the expected result is ***1***.

#### Example #2

Here is what we get for ***n = 21***:

- Initialization: ***k = 4*** because ***4² ≤ 21 < 5²***, which leads to ***L = [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ]***.
- Step #1: ***1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16***, which does not equal ***n***.
- Step #2: We increment ***k*** and we add ***2k + 1 = 2 x 5 - 1 = 9*** to the list: ***L = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]***.
- Step #3: We remove the first term from the list: ***L = [ 3, 5, 7, 9 ]***. The sum of the terms is now ***24***, which is still greater than ***n***. So we remove another term: ***L = [ 5, 7, 9 ]***.
- Step #1 : ***5 + 7 + 9 = 21***. We're done.

We went through two iterations. So the expected result is ***2***.

#### Example #3

Below is a summary of all steps for a slightly more complex example with ***n = 145***.

Initialization: ***k = 12*** because ***12² ≤ 145 < 13²***.

```
Iteration | Step | k  | L                                 | Sum
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    1     |  1   | 12 | 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23    | 144
          |  2   | 13 | 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25 | 169
          |  3   | 13 | 11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25           | 144
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    2     |  1   | 13 | 11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25           | 144
          |  2   | 14 | 11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27        | 171
          |  3   | 14 | 17,19,21,23,25,27                 | 132
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    3     |  1   | 14 | 17,19,21,23,25,27                 | 132
          |  2   | 15 | 17,19,21,23,25,27,29              | 161
          |  3   | 15 | 19,21,23,25,27,29                 | 144
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    4     |  1   | 15 | 19,21,23,25,27,29                 | 144
          |  2   | 16 | 19,21,23,25,27,29,31              | 175
          |  3   | 16 | 23,25,27,29,31                    | 135
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    5     |  1   | 16 | 23,25,27,29,31                    | 135
          |  2   | 17 | 23,25,27,29,31,33                 | 168
          |  3   | 17 | 25,27,29,31,33                    | 145
----------+------+----+-----------------------------------+----
    6     |  1   | 17 | 25,27,29,31,33                    | 145
```

We went through 6 iterations. So the expected result is ***6***.

#### Factorization of the input

This paragraph is for illustration purposes only. It describes how the factorization of the input can be deduced from the result of the algorithm.

Factorization of ***21***:

- *21 = 5 + 7 + 9 = (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9) - (1 + 3)*
- *21 = 5² - 2²*
- *21 = (5 + 2)(5 - 2)*
- *21 = 7 x 3*

#### Rules and clarifications

- The input is guaranteed to be a positive odd integer. It may be either a composite integer or a prime.
- You're required to process any odd ***n*** in ***[ 1, ..., 65535 ]*** in less than one minute on mid-range hardware.
- Given enough time, your program/function should theoretically work for any value of ***n*** that is natively supported by your language. If it doesn't, please explain why in your answer.
- You may use any other method instead of the described one as long as it returns the correct result.
- This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

#### Test cases

*To be completed*

Comment: Typo: you wrote "k²=n", which can't possibly be correct (and contradicts the rest of the post).

Comment: @ais523 Thanks for catching that out. (I believe all my "less than or equal to" signs where turned into equal signs when I copy/pasted through Notepad++.)

Comment: 1. There's also an extra `=` in the LaTeXified image. 2. You say it's a variant on an earlier question of yours, but it seems so similar that I don't see why it wouldn't be a dupe. If it isn't, I definitely think it's a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18349/194 : the two questions are essentially "Find the factorisation of `n` into two parts which are as close as possible to `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I think it's a dupe indeed.

Answer (score 0):

### Identify the variable case

Your task is to write a function which determines which casing convention a provided variable name belongs to:

- `camelCase`
- `kebab-case`
- `Train-Case`
- `snake_case`
- `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`
- `PascalCase`
- `Ada_Case` (not a real term, but apparently the standard casing used in Ada)

Your function should return one of the above strings, either exactly as above, or as spaced title-case: "Train case", "Screaming snake case".

Casings that include `-` or `_` may include leading or trailing `-`s or `_`s (eg, `__MY_SNAKE__` or `-webkit-kebab`).

Multiple consecutive upper case letters are allowed in mixed casings, as long as they follow a lower case letter (`MyXMLDocument`, `This-CSS-Crap`).

Where an input fits multiple schemes (eg, `F` or `foo`), you may return any valid classification.

If an input does not fit one of the above schemes (eg `stu-pid_case`), you must return something different. You may also throw an error.

The input string is guaranteed to be at least one character, and begin with a character matching `/[a-zA-Z_-]/`. Every other character will match `/[a-zA-Z0-9$-]/`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest length in bytes wins. Standard loopholes forbidden. Standard input and output methods.

#### Test cases

```
myFunkyVariable => camelCase
no-op => kebab-case
TEST2 => SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE
__c => snake_case
XML-Madness => Error
Get_Input => Ada_Case
i => camelCase (or snake_case)
char2int_factory => snake_case
```

Comment: You should specify exactly what each of the cases requires.  (e.g. train case is separated by underscores with only the first character capital)  Because this is a competition there should be no room for interpretation.

Comment: What ambiguity have I missed?

Comment: You should define what each of the 7 cases entails.  Currently you just list 7 examples, which is certainly helpful, but I don't think sufficient.

Comment: You really don't think they're sufficiently self-explanatory? I mean, I can add explanation, but I'm curious if you have an example of a variable name that you don't know how to classify?

Comment: I think I get it based on the examples and I think any reasonable person would be able to jump to the correct conclusion, but we should strive to make questions as concrete as possible.  Some people might not be aware of casing in the first place and definitions could help.  It may seem like I'm making a fuss over nothing, and perhaps I am, but I think it could only benefit to add specific definitions of the terms, since the question is about identifying them.  As far as examples go, I believe `E_S_S` is ambiguous between screaming snake and Ada. Definitions might help clear that up.

Comment: That one is ambiguous, which, as stated, means that either answer is ok. But I'll add an introductory paragraph about casing.

Answer (score 0):

## Dungeon of Botdom

Bots will play a variant of this game:

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/150312/welcome-dungeon

(Our version will be played by one bot versus another bot, and there will only be one character, which may or may not be in the actual game, and it will be repeated a bunch.)

Essentially, there is a deck of cards, with enemies on each card. players take turns either passing, or drawing a card and either a) placing it in the initially empty dungeon or b) removing a piece of gear and discarding the enemy. enemies have different hit points, which affects the damage done to a bot traversing the dungeon. When everyone but one player has passed, they enter the dungeon. when a bot is traversing the dungeon, they will encounter the enemies placed in the dungeon in LIFO order (the card on top is taken first) (if I take out some items this may be irrelevant). enemies are instantly defeated if the player has a corresponding item, otherwise the player takes damage equal to the enemies number. if a player makes it through the dungeon, they get one point. get two points to win the match. if they fall while traversing the dungeon, they lose one chance. fail twice, and the opponent wins the match.

What this means, is that you might want to do one of two things: make the dungeon too dangerous to survive without your opponent thinking it is, and passing, or making the opponent bot believe the dungeon is too dangerous, when it is not, and running through the dungeon and succeeding.

We'll have a good ol' round robin of a 1000 rounds each or some such. the nice thing about this game is that the rounds are short, because once you finish the deck, a player automatically enters the dungeon.

Comment: You may want to include a better description, not just the link.  Describe the various cards, the game mechanics, the format of the bots, and include the code for testing bots.  KOTH challenges tend to have lots of text.

Comment: @gryphon did I not do that? Also I haven't decided on the exact deck yet, and exact items, and exact round formats. I have described the basics of the game anyway

Comment: @Gryphon also I haven't made the controller yet. we can't all get away with straight posting to main because of our incredible talent for Koths and making the controllers immediately

Comment: OK, sorry.  I would just make sure I have the controller before I actually posted the question.

Comment: I have the controller finished [here](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/dungeon-of-botdom)

Comment: Nice Poem, @DestructibleLemon!

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiplicity of a Curve

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)[abstract-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given an polynomial `p` in two variables `x` and `y` as well as a point `(u,v)`, determine the *multiplicity* `m` of the curve `C = { (x,y) | p(x,y) = 0}` at the point `(u,v)`.

#### Details

- The *degree* of a monomial `a * x^i * y^j` in two variables is `d = i+j`.
- A polynomial is *homogeneous* if all its monomials have the same degree `d`.
- Any polynomial `p` (where `d` is the degree of `p`, i.e. the maximum of the degree of all its monomials) can uniquely be decomposed into a sum of polynomials `p = p0 + p1 + ... + pd` where each `pk` is homogeneous of degree `k` OR possibly zero.
- The *multiplicity* of a curve `C` given by the polynomial `p` at `(u,v)` can be determined using the following computation:

  - First decompose the polynomial `p(x-u,y-v)` (this is `p` with `x,y` replaced with `x-u,y-v`) into a sum of homogeneous polynomials as described above:

    ```
    p(x-u,y-v) = q0 + q1 + ... + qd
    ```
  - Then determine the minimal `k` such that `qk` is nonzero. Then the multiplicity is defined as `m := k`.

#### Example

Let us consider the polynomial `p(x,y) = -x^2 - 4x + y^2 - 2y -3` and the point `(u,v) = (-2,1)`.

```
p(x-u,y-v) = y^2 - x^3
```

So the decomposition is

```
p(x-u,y-v) = [0] + [0] + [y^2] + [-x^3]
```

Here the brackets are just used to highlight the homogeneous polynomials of each degree.

We see that `y^2` is the nonzero polynomial of least degree, so `m = 2`

#### TODO

- add more testcases

Comment: 1. My interpretation is that the multiplicity is just the minimum degree of all nonzero terms in the polynomial p(x-u, y-v). If this is true, stating so would simplify reading. 2. What input formats are permitted? Few languages have `Polynomial` as a type, so an input such as `[[0,1],[2,3]]` could be taken to represent `0x⁰y⁰ + 1x¹y⁰ + 2x⁰y¹ + 3x¹y¹`.

Comment: I did not add the formats yet, but these are the two I had in mind, as we did it in previous challenges.

Comment: Regarding the degree: Yes that is essentially what I wrote down, just a little bit more detailed for people who are not familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 0):

## Can my favourite team still become Football Champion? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

As a fan of an at most moderately successful football<sup>BE</sup> team, towards the end of the season I often wonder whether my favourite team still has any theoretical chance left of becoming champion. Your task in this challenge is to answer that question for me.

## Input

You will recieve three inputs: the current table, the list of remaining matches, and the current position of the team we are interested in.

**Input 1:** The *current table*, a sequence of numbers were the *i*-th number are the points gained by team *i* so far. For example, the input
`[93, 86, 78, 76, 75]` encodes the following table (only the last column is of importance):

[image: premier league table]

---

**Input 2**: The *remaining matches*, a sequence of tuples where each tuple (*i*,*j*) stands for a remaining match between team *i* and *j*. In the above example, a second input of `[(1,2), (4,3), (2,3), (3,2), (1,2)]` would mean that the remaining matches are:

```
Chelsea vs Tottenham, Liverpool vs Man. City, Tottenham vs Man. City, Man. City vs Tottenham, Chelsea vs Tottenham
```

---

**Input 3:** The *current position* of the team we are interested in. For example, an input of `2` for the above example would mean that we'd like to know whether Tottenham can still become champion.

## Output

For each remaining match of the form (*i*,*j*), there are three possible outcomes:

- Team *i* wins: Team *i* gets **3 points**, team *j* gets **0 points**
- Team *j* wins: Team *i* gets **0 points**, team *j* gets **3 points**
- Draw: Team *i* and *j* both get **1 point**

You must output a truthy value if there is some outcome for all remaining games such that at the end, no other team has more points than the team specified in the 3rd input. Otherwise, output a falsy value.

**Example**: Consider the exemplary input from the above section:

Input 1 = `[93, 86, 78, 76, 75]`,
Input 2 = `[(1,2), (4,3), (2,3), (3,2), (1,2)]`,
Input 3 = `2`

If team `2` wins all its remaining matches (i.e. `(1,2), (2,3), (3,2), (1,2)`), it gets 4*3 = 12 additional points; none of the other teams gets any points from these matches. Let's say the other remaining match (i.e. `(4,3)`) is a draw. Then the final scores would be:

```
 Team 1: 93, Team 2: 86 + 12 = 98, Team 3: 78 + 1 = 79, Team 4: 76 + 1 = 77, Team 5: 75
```

This means that we have already found some outcome for the remaining matches such that no other team has more points than team `2`, so the output for this input must be truthy.

## Details

- You may assume the first input to be an ordered sequence, i.e. for *i* < *j*, the *i*-th entry is equal to or greater than the *j*-th entry. The first input may be taken as a list, a string or the like.
- You may take the second input as a string, a list of tuples or the like. Alternatively, you may take it as a two-dimensional array `a` where `a[i][j]` is the number of entries of the form `(i,j)` in the list of remaining matches. For example, `a[1][2] = 2, a[2][3] = 1, a[3][2] = 1, a[4][3] = 1`
  corresponds to `[(1,2), (4,3), (2,3), (3,2), (1,2)]`.
- For the second and third input, you may assume 0-indexing instead of 1-indexing.
- You may take the three inputs in any order.

Please specify the exact input format you chose in your answer.

<sub>**Side node**: The problem underlying this challenge was shown to be NP-complete in "[Football Elimination is Hard to Decide Under the 3-Point-Rule](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=756600)". Interestingly, if only two points are awarded for a win, the problem becomes solvable in polynomial time.</sub>

## Test Cases

All test cases are in the format `Input1`, `Input2`, `Input3`.

**Truthy:**

- `[93, 86, 78, 76, 75]`, `[(1,2), (4,3), (2,3), (3,2), (1,2)]`, `2`
- `[50]`, `[]`, `1`
- `[10, 10, 10]`, `[]`, `3`
- `[15, 10, 8]`, `[(2,3), (1,3), (1,3), (3,1), (2,1)]`, `2`

**Falsy:**

- `[10, 9, 8]`, `[]`, `2`
- `[10, 9, 9]`, `[(2,3), (3,2)]`, `1`
- `[21, 12, 11]`, `[(2,1), (1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,3), (3,1), (3,1)]`, `2`

## Winner

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest correct answer (in bytes) wins. The winner will be chosen one week after the first correct answer is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Closely related to [Words from periodic table of elements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6284/46206) (but that one is closed due to unclear specification?).

Closely related to [Find the Chemistry of a name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58476/46206) (probably a dupe, slightly different requirements though).

Closely related to [[Br]eaking Code Golf [Ba]d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112608/46206) (allows strings to be not expressible as solely a sequence of element abbreviations).

*May I get a community consensus, whether this is better specified and/or sufficiently different to not be immediately closed as a dupe?*

### Elementize a string

Convert an input string to a concatenation of chemical element abbreviations.

Write a program/function/procedure etc. which will take as input a string/array of characters/pointer to a string etc. and return/print/display the same string expressed as a concatenation of chemical element abbreviations.

For example, `takagi` can be expressed as `TaKAgI` (i.e. the abbreviations for Tantalum(Ta), Potassium(K), Silver(Ag), Iodine(I)).

For this challenge you must use the following element name abbreviations:

```
{"H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg",
"Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr",
"Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br",
"Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd",
"Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "La",
"Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er",
"Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au",
"Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Th",
"Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md",
"No", "Lr", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn"}
```

These are the elements with numbers 1 through 112. You may optionally also use the abbreviations for elements 113 through 118:

```
{"Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og"}
```

You may not, however, use the placeholder three-letter abbreviations for not yet named elements, such as `"Uuo"` (Ununoctium).

If the input string cannot be expressed by the above abbreviations, you shall return one of the following:

- a falsey value (clearly distinct from element names, in other words `A` would not be valid, even though there is no element "A"; something like `0`, `null`, `false`, `newline` is fine)
- an empty string
- exit without output
- exit with an error
- something similarly unambiguous signifying failure and not returning some incorrect output that could be accidentally misinterpreted as an answer *(suggestions to make this specification clearer?)*

Possible output, using example input `takagi`:

- an appropriately capitalized string: `TaKAgI`.
- a flat array of characters `{"T", "a", "K", "A", "g", "I"}` with appropriate capitalization.
- a list of strings (capitalized or not) separated by newlines or as separate members of an array, etc., e.g. `ta \n k \n ag \n i`.

The rule of thumb is that the division into separate elements must be clear. *Please comment if additional clarification is needed!*

You may assume the input to be a single word consisting only of letters.

**Compression is not the intent of this challenge!** Boiler-plate code that fetches the list of elements from somewhere, hard-coding the lists of abbreviations, assuming the list of abbreviations to be stored in a variable or passed as a second argument to your function is OK and should not be included in the byte count.

```
Sample input -> sample output
no -> No             // as in Nobelium, alternatively see next line
no -> NO             // Nitrogen-Oxygen, either one is valid
helium -> falsey output
heliam -> HeLiAm
fog -> FOg           // If using 118 elements, falsey otherwise.
ppcg -> falsey       // I'm really, really sorry
```

Suggestions of further test cases are appreciated.

This is code-golf, shortest code wins.

Comment: Potassium is `K`, not `P`.

Comment: @calculator brain-fart, fixed, thanks.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to work on improving the existing closed question than to post a duplicate.

Comment: @Peter I should have realized sooner, that a [chemistry] tag exists here. I'm not sure I'm at ease with modifying someone else' challenge (distorting their intent?) and potentially invalidating others' answers...

Answer (score 0):

## How many substitutions till palindromization?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome)

Given a string, find the minimum number of character substitutions needed so that the string is a palindrome.

E.g. the string `abchefa` needs 2 substitutions, so it can take any of the following paths:

```
abchefa -> afchefa -> afehefa
                   -> afchcfa
        -> abehefa -> afehefa
                   -> abeheba
        -> abchcfa -> afchcfa
                   -> abchcba
        -> abcheba -> abeheba
                   -> abchcba
```

You must return a minimal number, e.g. `abc` can use 3 substitutions (`abc -> dbc -> ddc -> ddd`) but it really only needs 1 (`abc -> aba`) so you must return 1.

The string will only contain printable ASCII, no newlines.

Additional testcases:

```
Input
Output


0

A
0

!@
1

1234567890
5

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
47

aaabaaacaqadaaq
3

o_O WTF RLY?!
6
```

## Rules

- You can take the string as a string or as a list of chars, but not as a list of strings
- You must return a minimal value in a generally accepted output format.

Comment: I thought there was a near-dupe somewhere, but I'm pretty sure [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57719/42545) is the one I was thinking of...

Comment: Actually this *might* be a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123833/42545): perform any answer for all indexes in the string, sum, divide by two.

Comment: @ETHproductions You spoiled the hidden way to do it...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen an exact dupe, although it might still be in the sandbox; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95343/194 is a generalisation.

Answer (score 0):

## Help me golf my numbers! (Part 2) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Thanks for all your help in [Part 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124192/help-me-golf-my-numbers-part-1)! I recently just found out that my language also supports expressions, and we can use those to make our numbers even shorter!

## Challenge

Write a *full program* that takes in a list of integers less than 2^53-1. For each integer, rewrite it in the shortest way possible using expressions, and output the result.

## Allowed operators

The operators below are given in order of precedence from highest to lowest, with groups separated by empty lines. (These precedence levels are the same as Python.) All binary operators are left-associative, except exponentiation, which is right-associative. Note that some operators are two bytes in length.

```
**: Exponentiation

* : Multiplication
/ : Integer Division
% : Modulus

+ : Addition
- : Subtraction
~ : Bitwise NOT

<<: Left shift
>>: Right shift

& : Bitwise AND

^ : Bitwise XOR

| : Bitwise OR
```

You may use decimal, hexadecimal, or scientific notation to represent integers in your output (the answers to [Part 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124192/help-me-golf-my-numbers-part-1) will help you choose the shortest representation for each integer). You may also use parentheses to group subexpressions.

## Scoring

I will post a list of 1000 integers to be used as the test battery. A program's score will be the size of the output for the provided test, where the lowest score wins. A solutions is invalid if any of the expressions do not evaluate to the given integer. There will also be an execution time limit of 20 minutes for all 1000 inputs (roughly 1 second per input) in order to discourage brute-force solutions.

Numbers for the test battery will be chosen according to the following algorithm:

```
def choose():
    msb = randint(0, 52)
    return randint(0, 1 << msb)
```

with duplicates filtered out.

## Sandbox

- Is there anything here that can be clarified?
- Anything else that can make this challenge more fun?

Comment: **Sandbox #2** - I don't think bitwise operators will make it too broad. **#3** The community has generally agreed that penalties do not make the challenge any more interesting. **General advice**- make some more rules. Clarify what you mean by "shorten them as much as possible", I had to read that three times to understand. And what do you mean by takes a *list* of integers? How does one shorten a list using arithmetic?

Comment: You should specify how your expressions handle precedence and associativity. I assume expressions can use any number literals?

Comment: I think it would be good to say something about you're choosing numbers for the test battery. If they are random, heuristic solutions will be effective (or maybe just hardcoding?). Or, if you intentionally choose inputs that benefit from rarely-useful operations like `%, that would be useful to optimize for.

Comment: @xnor Yes, they may. I'll add information about precedence and associativity as well.

Comment: @xnor Good point. My plan was to choose randomly, do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: I think random would be good. Maybe with some bias towards shorter numbers so they're not all 50-ish bits. It might hard though to beat hardcoding, though the bitwise operations might help. Perhaps you could try to hand-optimizing some random numbers and see how well you do. I think you also need something to rule out brute-force solutions, like a run-time bound.

Comment: I feel like this might be a dupe.

Comment: @Shaggy could you link to the duplicate please?

Comment: I haven't figured out the right search terms to get me there yet.

Comment: @xnor I added a possible algorithm for choosing numbers as well as a time bound. Do you think this is ready for posting?

Comment: @musicman523 Having thought about it a bit more, I worry hardcoding the number is too effective. It seems really unlikely a random number allows a shorter arithmetic expression than its digit length. I'm not even sure such a number would appear in 1000 samples.

Comment: I agree. I previously entered 'there can be only one' ( https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92962/there-can-be-only-1 ),  which was simliar but only allowed using '1'. I don't believe the operators will be useful for almost all numbers, and if you require an operator is used people will just use '+1' most of the time.

While a break from your original plan, you could (for example) require using scientific notation, with one number before and after the 'e', so things like '2e5' and '3e7'. That would make operators required and useful.

Comment: Maybe make operators cost less than digits. e.g each operator is 2 and each digit is 5 in order to discourage hardcoding

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll probably revive this at some point. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

### Reverse divmod

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

### Introduction

The `divmod` function is one that is included in many standard libraries and is defined as follows:

[image]

Or, in other words, `divmod(a,b)` returns a list containing the integer quotient of `a/b` (i.e. `floor(a/b)`) and `mod(a,b)` (i.e. the remainder in the division of `a/b`).

Your challenge is not to *implement* the `divmod`function, but rather *reverse* it.

### Input

You will take two integers `x` and `y` as input, in any reasonable input format (two integers, list, etc.). Both `x` and `y` are guaranteed to be in the range `-2^31` to `2^31-1`, inclusive.

### Output

The output of your code shall be two integers, in any reasonable output format (two integers, list, etc.). Note that you must output the two integers in such a way that a human is able to distinguish one from another.
These two integers should be an `a` and `b` such that `divmod(a,b)==(x,y)` (i.e. `floor(a/b)==x && mod(a,b)==y`). Please specify in your answer how these two integers are outputted if it is not immediately clear (for example, if you output `b` before `a`).

Remember that this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in bytes wins!

Comment: Note to self: add I/O examples

Comment: So: given `x` and `y` output `x*b+y, b` for any `b > y` if `y` is positive or `b < y` if `y` is negative? Or have I missed something?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No you haven't, I realized that the challenge is much simpler than I originally thought (because of the method you mentioned). I am going to try and increase the difficulty later.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert a simulated Ken Thompson virus into a program [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

A [Ken Thompson virus](http://wiki.c2.com/?TheKenThompsonHack) is a virus that infects your compiler and other programs. Since it infects all your tools, you can not detect it without using tools from before the virus was introduced.

Your will create a prototype for inserting the Ken Thompson virus into code. The goal of this virus will be to allow you to (fake) destroy any computer running a program infected with it.

Inserting a Ken Thompson virus is defined as follows. Start with an input program `P`. Your program will output a modified program `Q` that works as follows:

- If the input to `Q` is `aNouIQ5xKvUfdZVzo0Xs`, it will output `BOOM` (in a real Ken Thompson virus, this would actually do something bad, but since it this is a fake virus, outputing `BOOM` is done instead).
- For any other input to `Q`, run program `P` with that input

  - If the output of `P` is valid source code in the language you are using, insert the Ken Thompson virus into it and then `Q` will output the resulting infected program.
  - Otherwise, the output of `Q` is just the output of `P`.

You will write a program that takes `P`'s code as input and produces `Q`'s code as output.

You can use either a currently (at the time of this post) existing programming language, or a subset of one, for this challenge. (The idea is that language you are using would be the target language of some self-compiling compiler, but this is not required.) Since you want to be as subtle as possible, the shortest code (in bytes) wins!

Comment: Main site entry is here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/124581/16842

Answer (score 0):

## This question is up for adoption!  If you would like to finish and post it, please include a little mention for @gryphon :)

## Battle of the Bots

### Your Task

Program a bot to compete in a battle with other bots.  Each robot has fifteen flags situated around their exterior.  Your goal is to have at least one flag left on your robot for as long as possible.  Each turn you will move diagonally (or not at all) on a square grid with a width/length equal to the number of bots competing squared (attempting to move off the edge of the grid will result in either you moving adjacent to your previous position, or no movement at all if attempting to move from a corner), and use two or less of the four weapons/shields that are situated facing along the horizontal and vertical rows of the grid.  You will choose which weapon you would prefer to have in each of your four slots at the beginning of the game.  After 2,500 turns, each bot with flags remaining will receive a 500 point bonus, and the game will end.  If all flags have been destroyed before this time, the game will end then.  The winner will be the person with the most points at the end of 1,000 matches.

### Your Code

Each bot will begin in a randomly chosen location on the playing field (bots may be on top of each other).  Your code will take the form of two python 2.7 functions, one named (name of your submission) start, which will take no input and return 4 values, one for each weapon/shield slot.  The first value will be the top of the bot, and they will continue in clockwise order.  The integer values to be returned and weapons/shields they represent are shown below:

1: Firestarter, a weapon that will start a fire adjacent to the bot.  Fires start at class 1 and increment upward every turn.  If, at the start of a bot's turn they are on top of a fire they lose flags equal to the level of the fire.  If a fire is at level 3, it spreads fires of level 1 to all directly (not diagonally) adjacent squares that are not already on fire.  When a fire reaches level 8, rather than becoming  a level 8 fire, it dies, turning back to an "O" on the map, having used up all available burning material.  It may then be lit on fire again in the future.

2: Laser, a weapon that destroys one flag on any bot in a straight line from its firing point outwards from the bot.

3: Buzzsaw, a weapon that destroys five flags on any bot adjacent to the bot using it on the side it is used on.

4: Shield, a defensive mechanism that protects flags from lasers and buzzsaws, and is unaffected by our next weapon.

5: Acid Sprayer, a weapon that destroys the weapon facing it on any bot within three spaces of the bot using it in a straight line (not an arc) from its mounting point

Your second function will receive, first the turn number, second a map of the battlefield in a string, with "R" representing robots (including itself), "O" representing empty space, and the level a fire is at representing any fires.  The end of a row will be shown with a semicolon ";".  For example, if the battlefield looks like this:

```
OORO131OO
OOOOO1OOO
ROOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
OOOOOROOO
OOOOOOOOO
```

Each bot will receive this:

```
OORO131OO;OOOOO1OOO;ROOOOOOOO;OOOOOOOOO;OOOOOOOOO;OOOOOOOOO;OOOOOOOOO;OOOOOROOO;OOOOOOOOO
```

Next, the bot will receive its X coordinate, and then its Y coordinate, 0 indexed and with the top left corner being 0,0.  Finally, the bot will receive how many flags it has remaining.

If multiple bots are in the same square, only a single "R" will be shown.  If a bot is standing on the same square as a fire, only the fire will be shown.  A bot can tell if it is standing on a fire if its own X and Y coordinates show an integer rather than a "R".

### Sample Bots

Will show sample bots here when they are completed

### Controller

Will show controller here when it is completed

### Additional Rules

- No copying other bots, or copying with only minor changes.
- No messing around with the judging process, other bots, or writing programs to acquire information that does not come from the inputs given to them, randomizers, or other legitimate sources of information.
- No writing bots specifically designed to prop up other bots.
- Maximum of three submissions per user.

## Meta:

Is the explanation clear enough?

Are there any loopholes for programs to exploit?

Any tags other than [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)?

Comment: There are a few points which I think could be clearer. 1. The description of the goal ("*on average ... one or more flags left on it for the longest period of time*") doesn't seem to match the actual scoring mechanism. 2. Must the weapon selection be deterministic? 3. Does a fire spread to adjacent cells on the turn that it becomes level 3 or on the next turn? 4. How do multiple fires interact? 5. Having burnt to level 8, can a cell be set on fire again in the future? 6. Does the acid sprayer work along the same axis-aligned line as the laser, or does it hit in a semicircle?

Comment: 7. How does a bot know whether the cell it is currently standing in is on fire? 8. I assume that movement is blocked at the edges, but this could be more explicit.

Comment: Edited to fix concerns.

Comment: you should probably use classes rather than two functions, since the ability to remember how opponents behave is useful.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon, I've actually moved on from this challenge now, so consider it abandoned.  If you want, you can take it over.

Comment: But... if I did that I would have three koths on the waiting list!

Comment: Wow, that is a lot.  I dropped it because I'm working on a new language, but I may readopt it if no one else does after I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the Harmonic Mean

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of a sequence of numbers is the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the reciprocal of each number. For example, the harmonic mean of `[1, 2, 3]` is `1/((1/1+1/2+1/3)/3)` = `3/(1/1+1/2+1/3)`.

#### Input

A list/array/tuple/string with some delimeter/etc. of positive integers which fit within the standard integer/float type of your language of choice.

#### Output

The harmonic mean of those integers, accurate to at least 6 (?) decimal places.

#### Test Cases

```
input => output

1 4 4 => 2.0

1 2 3 => 1.63636

527 => 527.0

52 33 400 => 52.6548

7 20 333 45 1 => 4.10481
```

Comment: Sub-challenge of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37217/31625).

Comment: If you're going to specify the output accuracy in decimal places you need to restrict the input such that it's possible. A 64-bit floating point number (`double`) can represent about 16 significant decimal figures, but it can represent numbers up to a bit more than 10^300.

Comment: @PeterTaylor not really sure how to handle this... I want people to  be able to use the most natural method without allowing silly abuses such as  "I can only handle one decimal place" or something.

Comment: If you guarantee that there will be at most 20 numbers, all in the range `1E-8` to `1E8` then I think that should easily be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

As I sometimes build bots, I often came across real time image reading. The goal in this problem is to be able to identify a character given pixel representation with the minimal amount of tests. For that, you will have to generate a tree that can identify any char.

### Input

- A list of frequency
- A png file containing each char in a 1 wide red box. Its exact color is #ed1c24 and it is not present in any of the chars.

### Output

A series of specific test that can identify any char. A test is defined by the pixel coordinates, the exact colour to check, the list of chars to have this pixel and the list of chars that donot.

### Example

Let's have a look at only four chars (number 1-4) of equal frequency.

[image: Test]

Here we could say that we check for the for pixel in 0,0 (upper left corner). If it is white, it means it's a 1, otherwise we check for the pixel 1,0 (to the right of the upper left corner). If this one is white, it's a 4, otherwise we check for the pixel in 2,2 (the blanck beetween the 3 and the box). If it is white, it's a 3, otherwise it's a 2.

That way we can identify any number in 3 tests at most. If we calculate our score with this layout, it would be `0.25x1 + 0.25x3 + 0.25x3 + 0.25x2 = 2.25` so on average our tree needs 2.25 pixel reading to identify a number.

The solution that lead to that is written like this:

```
[0,0], [255,255,255], [1], [2,3,4]
[1,0], [255,255,255], [4], [2,3]
[2,2], [255,255,255], [3], [2]
```

However the best solution for this example has a score of 2. One of the trees that lead to that is

```
[0,1], [255,255,255], [1,4], [2,3]
[0,0], [255,255,255], [1], [4]
[2,2], [255,255,255], [3], [2]
```

### Rules

- Count each time you read a pixel.
- Use the number frequency to average your score
- Your score is the sum of the char frequency times the number of pixels read to identify this number.

Comment: What do you mean by 'any number'? If it is more than 1,2,3,4, you should demonstrate what these additional numbers look like.

Comment: Good point. I meant any chars, I extended the problem while writting it. I will fix this

Answer (score 0):

## Sources and Strings

**The challenge:**
Output a string with the same length as the source code.

**The requirements:**

- Standard loopholes apply, etc., etc.
- Input may not be taken
- The output must be deterministic (for scoring purposes)
- Output must be a string
- Functions and full programs are allowed, no snippets though

**The scoring:**
This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins. However, for each individual character in the source that has a match in the outputted string, your byte score is increased by 2 bytes.

Examples of scoring (of course, most of these aren't working programs):

```
Program            Output            Score
nn                 ng                2+(1*2)=4
print('h'*14);     hhhhhhhhhhhhhh    14+(1*2)=16
print('prnt'*4);   prntprntprntprnt  16+(8*2)=32
q                  q                 1+(1*2)=3
qwertyuiop         mmmmmmmmmm        10+(0*2)=10
System.out.println("lol");           Invalid=Infinity points
```

Comment: [Related, possible dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59436/58974)

Comment: Related, but not a dupe IMO.

Comment: [Related, more possibly a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/58974) and illustrates that there will be a *lot* of one byte solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

## Prime Factors Zip

Take an integer strictly greater than 2, for example `66`. Its prime factors are `[2,3,11]`, when ordered from smallest to biggest. If we zip the digits of those factors, we get `[231,1]`. Multiplying them yields the integer `231`.

If we apply this process back on `231`, we get `371`. If we apply this multiple times, we get the following sequence:

```
66
231
371
225
3355
5676
290082
770229
174999300
121860997014
6330393355581
40168037420160
6869559509647641812624
0
```

At this point, we stop because `0` cannot be factored. We say that `0` is the *prime factors zip* of `66`.

If we start with `19`, we get the following sequence:

```
19
9
33
31
3
3
…
```

Here, we can see that once we reach `3`, we will always get `3`. Therefore, `3` is the *prime factors zip* of `19`.

If we start with `22`, we get the following sequence:

```
22
21
37
21
37
…
```

Here, we can see that once we reach `21`, we will always get the loop `[21,37]`. Therefore, `[21,37]` is the *prime factors zip* of `22`.

Note that it is possible for an integer to be its own prime factors zip (e.g. `5`) or that it is contained in its prime factors zip (e.g. `23` which has prime factors zip `[23,6]`).

### Task

Given an integer strictly greater than `1`, output its prime factors zip.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

#### Test Cases

```
Input        Prime factors zip
7            7
46           0
48           [22103,72463]
100          0
113          3
1337         [337,63]
```

#### Sandbox

I have no idea (nor have I checked extensively) if it is possible than this procedure never loops for some integers.

Comment: I'd suggest explaining "zip" more precisely. I think it is more commonly called "transpose" and you could try to visualise it by drawing out a matrix? For the never looping thing, I think you can just say the programs don't have to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

## Color the Grayscale

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Given an image containing only grayscale colors (for RGB, `R==G==B`), and a RGB value (that is not grayscale), color the image with your given color.

//Is there a formula that does this? If so this can definitely have objective input and output.

Should this be [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) like a lot of the other [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) challenges?

Answer (score 0):

## Print all video urls of YouTube channel [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf)

Inspired by [Count the videos in a Youtube Playlist](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122740/48734), the input will be the "VIDEOS" view from a channel like this one:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzwJRQXMXkaB9KlqUdFD74Q/videos
```

The output will be a complete, newline-delimited list of all video urls the respective channel has to offer. It would look something like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxNfccUIQCU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOr0XIHFhlk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3tZElWLrbc
```

This is codegolf, so shortest answer wins.

---

Comments:

- I am unsure whether the permitted use of Google's YouTube API might be a good idea. It requires an API_KEY and can only retrieve 50 results per request.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## Patch Tuesdays Calendar

**Context**

Patch Tuesday happens every second Tuesday of the month, Microsoft and other companies release their monthly security patch on that Tuesday.

**Challenge**

The challenge is to write a program that writes 24 consecutive Patch Tuesdays dates separated by newline to the console. The Tuesdays must be the ones of the current year and the next year (not a parameter). Date format must be  mm/dd/yyyy.

**Winning**

Code with the fewest bytes wins, there are no bonuses.

**Meta**

Is there a good write up with conventions for golf questions?

Answer (score 0):

### **Challenge**

My challenge, is for you to generate a [Menger Sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) based on the `level`/`iteration` given. You need to draw it in `3d`, see the `Specifications` below!

**3D Specifications**

- You can use existing 3D libraries

**Examples**

*Inputs:* `0, 1, 2, 3`

*Outputs:*

[image: Diagram]

---

### **Background Information**

**What is a Menger Sponge**

> In mathematics, the Menger sponge (also known as the Menger universal curve) is a fractal curve. It is a three-dimensional generalization of the Cantor set and Sierpinski carpet

**Properties**

> See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge#Properties (too long to copy and paste)

**How do I construct the sponge?**

[image: Diagram]

1. > Begin with a cube  (first image).
2. > Divide every face of the cube into 9 squares, like a Rubik's Cube. This will sub-divide the cube into 27 smaller cubes.
3. > Remove the smaller cube in the middle of each face, and remove the smaller cube in the very center of the larger cube, leaving 20 smaller cubes (second image). This is a level-1 Menger sponge (resembling a Void Cube).
4. > Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each of the remaining smaller cubes, and continue to iterate ad infinitum.

> The second iteration gives a level-2 sponge (third image), the third iteration gives a level-3 sponge (fourth image), and so on. The Menger sponge itself is the limit of this process after an infinite number of iterations.

**Credit**

Background info taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) wikipedia page on Menger Sponges.

---

### **Good Luck!**

Remember this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest program wins!

---

### **HELP**

I need help with specifications for the `3d` output:

> Since 3D is now required (invalidating existing answers), I think the question is now unclear. There is a lot you need to specify for 3D including but not limited to viewing angle, projection, lighting, shading.

Comment: This may be a bit too much for the usual golfing techniques. 3D graphics isn't easy to golf.

Comment: @Daffy Then, should I try making it a coding challenge?

Comment: @downvoters - Noah has [listened to advice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126210/menger-sponge-generator#comment310693_126210) and posted this in sandbox.  If you downvote, please give some specific indication of what you think could be improved

Comment: @NoahCristino Personally, I think it would make a better coding challenge, yes.

Comment: @Daffy If the question is about implementing a 3D rendering engine (I don't think it is) then you are probably right.  However, if the OP chooses to allow the use of existing 3D libraries (which would not be untypical for this site), then I don't see a problem with it being [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @Daffy Ok, well I still need to specify the 3d specifications better.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I would like to keep it code golf, since people have already coded it like this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG8ZK-rRkXo

Comment: I'll edit and say that you can use existing 3d libraries.

Comment: @Daffy who said challenges need to be easy? There's a question with 250+ upvotes asking for Tetris inside of Conway's game of life...

Comment: @steenbergh Hah! Very very good point.

Comment: Could output be as a list of vertices, with you providing a default renderer? This would eliminate the need for a 3d-render on the part of the answerer, might simplify things a bit...

Comment: @steenbergh What if it was the `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates of each block?

Comment: @NoahCristino That would come too far off of your 3d-idea, I believe. Unless you'd make this about voxels, perhaps?.

Comment: @steenbergh but, you still technically outputting a representation of a Menger Sponge

Answer (score 0):

## Help me play Battleship! [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)

[Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) is a two-player guessing game in which each player guesses the placement of the opponent's ships, placed on a grid.

Each column is labeled with a letter, and each row with a number. The label starts from top left (`A` and `1`), and descends as you move right/down.

Each player is given two grids, one for placing ships, and one for guessing the enemy's ship placement. Each player places 5 ships -- one ship of length 5, one ship of length 4, two ships of length 3, and one ship of length 2 -- on her grid, either horizontally or vertically. The players should not share their ship placements.

After placing all ships, each player takes turn guessing the opponent's ship placements. The guessing player guesses one position, and the defending player must announce "hit" or "miss," depending on whether she (the defending player) had a ship there. When all positions of a ship is hit, it is "sunk."

The player who sinks all of the opponent's ships win.

This is an example of a battleship board (taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

### Task

Given the list of guesses a player has made, construct a 10x10 array that represents the board.

### Rules

- The input can take any reasonable format, as long as it is explained. Some examples are `[[position, result], [position, result], ...]` and `[[hit positions], [miss positions]]`.
- The output array can have any characters, as long as empty, "hit," and "miss" squares are distinguishable from one another. (e.g. `unknown = 0, hit = 1, miss = 2`)
- You may **not** take the list of unknown grid positions in the input.

### Test Cases

[Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/KhRBqSRj)

## Sandbox

- Is this challenge interesting?
- Are there any dupes? (I couldn't find one)
- Did I include too much detail in the introduction? (If so, what should I remove?)
- Are my test cases sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

## I Got All Night

---

### Meta

- Is this interesting?
- Has this already been submitted?
- Issues/loopholes in the rules?
- Suitable tags?

### The goal

Make a program that takes as much time as possible to complete. That's it.

### Rules

- It must not be infinite. `while(1){}` will not be accepted.
- You must be able to show how long it will take. Either through calculating it or by measuring it.
- It must be doing something non-trivial. `for(var x=0; x<1000000000000; x++){y++;}` will not be accepted.

### Scoring

Your score is the time it takes to complete in milliseconds divided by the size of the program in bytes. Round to the nearest point if needed.

For example, if your program is 95 bytes long and takes 3 hours to complete, your score is (3*60*60*1000)/95 = 113,684 (rounded)

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

Comment: busy beaver tag?

Comment: also nontrivial is a bad requirement

Comment: The main issue here is that time taken isn't objectively measurable on regular computers. Further, "trivial" is also not objective. Any computable task is largely equivalent to the for loop you have, besides some "minor" details.

Comment: also be prepared for answers that would go past the heat death of the universe

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Please don't post so many short comments, this isn't a chat room. Take time to think through what you want to say, and say it all at once. You can edit your comments for a couple minutes to add more details you realised that you omitted.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The wording I was going to use was "useful" instead of "non-trivial", but I figured that was even less descript. Do you have any suggestions for that? Also, what if I write a python script that measures computer speed (i.e. spinning around in a loop for 10 seconds, incrementing a variable) to normalize for different computer speeds?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon That's what I meant by `Either through calculating it or by measuring it`. If you can calculate that your program will take 15 billion years, then it's completely usable. Converting 15 billion years to milliseconds might be a hassle though ;)

Comment: You would have to run all the submissions yourself then, however the problem will then be answers that take too long to verify. Calculations would be very difficult to say, for example, what if my program will only run on some ancient computer, will I be able to use that clock time? Also what about context switches/interrupts/etc? Generally I don't think this kind of challenge works, it's sort of like why world records for "shortest concert" don't exist anymore: programs that take forever are not really programs.

Comment: I think this ground has been well-covered by existing challenges to make large numbers and this would add anything new.

Answer (score 0):

## [Star Trekkin'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZS2-4-iUJ4)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)

> Just an idea at this stage; wanted to get it down lest I forget it. I'll come back to it in a few days to work out the details.

### Challenge

Generate an ASCII art representation of the USS Enterprise with an animated, randomised ASCII starfield behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Programming Challenge: 
Winning criterion is the shortest byte program which can tell me (x, y) which number "x" was doubled in the list, and which number "y" was removed from the list of 1000 numbers from 1 to 1000.

Given a list of 1000 positive integers in random order, find the integer that is repeated more than once, the integers that are not present in the range [1,1000] and output the count of the repeated integer present in the list.

The format of the list is a space deliminated text file such as this:

```
779 990 5 814 353
627 173 797 714 619
802 719 895 966 325
275 158 322 215 271
631 232 175 10 397
892 124 26 287 878
757 754 508 871 255
363 159 482 400 247
223 857 862 18 434
919 335 586 65 579
828 943 366 874 999
238 289 362 600 321
193 863 613 930 143
107 879 530 284 110
437 426 981 546 924
701 441 941 43 614
542 727 694 351 643
794 563 476 834 624
804 634 776 672 57
597 338 748 908 156
297 234 444 598 891
925 163 229 791 326
944 182 262 987 734
582 910 567 132 28
645 962 994 6 917
617 64 106 304 404
88 93 849 882 677
749 254 12 399 897
329 988 31 379 654
25 646 134 445 327
577 848 673 551 408
405 806 244 40 601
497 177 972 526 545
796 755 630 663 423
428 562 610 1 686
548 281 101 154 747
763 32 236 368 956
639 522 507 792 771
693 147 728 203 845
615 889 931 440 299
348 707 235 320 295
803 513 703 940 717
205 150 702 189 183
296 875 575 454 492
194 425 126 657 976
570 809 945 825 168
890 217 656 29 550
684 188 78 221 446
523 952 676 900 583
484 933 268 608 708
665 17 963 212 253
432 964 858 909 316
155 120 114 210 477
319 647 822 409 388
818 308 77 102 373
929 113 402 841 213
470 877 648 968 135
309 824 690 844 463
323 240 706 391 653
372 985 346 788 510
991 554 494 44 915
758 756 989 759 659
534 142 939 675 378
974 345 462 54 942
681 1000 7 716 415
42 264 996 438 464
386 350 197 141 84
123 127 811 853 516
60 49 277 70 986
98 733 905 978 103
390 230 501 449 731
34 370 541 958 466
251 71 108 846 260
576 830 100 140 529
869 333 303 664 589
856 777 427 187 184
305 766 829 136 456
786 401 737 961 475
412 887 178 91 698
448 433 62 519 832
314 957 861 898 683
983 515 893 220 817
979 149 267 3 63
458 473 139 970 835
666 119 967 695 343
242 947 41 47 623
973 53 354 74 816
121 471 151 246 369
499 45 593 691 376
111 46 226 83 431
274 606 506 265 753
79 387 451 883 525
479 744 162 949 8
292 95 97 324 823
315 152 394 671 718
347 836 50 195 360
812 566 725 612 923
537 911 620 51 328
243 19 556 592 288
334 298 873 655 443
705 66 767 604 285
760 896 474 406 73
918 688 667 914 730
729 826 959 774 543
594 192 27 948 912
491 419 341 518 55
146 787 495 904 172
469 761 840 626 637
144 616 465 712 660
785 365 250 636 384
208 2 174 864 839
741 410 621 342 442
245 568 998 485 216
960 224 239 782 855
291 355 860 807 936
920 56 669 561 697
112 270 715 913 938
364 851 467 751 468
450 995 609 490 72
674 713 640 185 801
361 742 38 784 167
225 743 692 790 907
859 762 569 115 521
116 200 580 632 997
85 82 249 207 486
218 196 14 932 867
429 258 125 793 69
865 385 902 222 531
611 658 318 935 980
808 23 105 722 300
520 30 420 286 662
227 581 745 585 928
330 638 358 587 16
452 635 736 489 252
89 951 137 591 721
880 555 204 535 769
9 820 605 854 148
128 934 396 480 307
161 711 750 704 651
696 133 813 789 517
263 775 553 75 992
293 190 916 273 602
461 11 977 202 764
483 76 52 773 723
870 872 498 359 868
67 544 504 279 833
599 48 171 687 80
547 336 417 642 181
558 906 256 219 81
866 810 709 186 668
572 145 209 739 682
847 752 720 332 393
770 965 574 629 176
746 306 138 798 15
528 778 392 457 726
337 39 86 380 160
493 211 436 180 241
795 94 955 837 214
584 954 117 549 59
340 805 367 927 633
946 738 819 487 557
768 4 37 827 596
511 628 381 68 679
838 179 603 680 13
231 650 35 700 735
975 595 502 301 424
527 678 950 280 532
649 685 710 539 903
248 276 571 500 435
560 109 926 588 278
414 509 237 169 740
885 118 430 382 689
481 311 199 993 821
261 447 540 357 92
129 131 953 375 377
852 61 191 228 937
122 418 439 573 198
331 302 505 644 283
421 416 36 894 884
831 22 24 104 876
371 272 622 312 578
459 395 455 536 374
969 403 565 269 389
552 90 164 922 781
503 460 524 206 356
130 259 533 294 157
901 422 290 514 982
641 661 478 559 496
282 512 266 257 538
765 564 96 783 724
843 317 411 799 652
488 310 349 313 413
453 886 58 971 20
921 618 815 850 99
339 87 21 472 699
33 607 800 352 899
233 166 780 407 625
670 201 170 383 772
344 376 881 984 590
165 732 153 398 842
```

For example in this list 376 is repeated twice, and 888 is removed once.
In this challenge a number "x" can only be repeated "once", so the number "888" can only be removed once, so an acceptable output for a programmed answer
is this "(x, y)" where "x" is the number repeated twice, and "y" is the number removed.

I attempted to make this programming question, but because I included a bonus for web-scraping, and the format of the output for an answer was not clear it didn't receive positive reviews.

So I would like suggestions I how I can make this challenge clearer. Thank you.

Here is my challenge and the comments I received.

[Programming Challenge: Tell me which number I repeated, how many times, and which one I skipped?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126743/programming-challenge-tell-me-which-number-i-repeated-how-many-times-and-whic?noredirect=1#comment311825_126743)

Comment: I have gone through and made the challenge clearer here: https://hastebin.com/ucesohawok.md Feel free to use or disregard this. However, one of my suggestions is to loosen the I/O formats (meaning stating _input and output can be in any reasonable format_). This would mean that the list could be taken as a list/array instead of a string. Same thing for output. This is ultimately up to you, but note that it is discouraged to restrict I/O formats as you have done.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: My first reaction was that this is too straightforward to golf, but thinking more led to some interesting tricks. I think this is a nice challenge.

Comment: I suggest relaxing the input format and also allow a list or array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Working For The Weekend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zL8G5pBZ5CI&t=144s)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

### Option 1

Taking no input, output `true` if today is Saturday or Sunday or `false` otherwise.

---

### Option 2

Taking no input, output how many days, from today, until the weekend.

```
Sunday:    0
Monday:    5
Tuesday:   4
Wednesday: 3
Thursday:  2
Friday:    1
Saturday:  0
```

---

> ### Sandbox
>
> - Which option do you prefer?
> - Too trivial?
> - Dupe?
> - Allow local times to be used or require UTC? (I *wanna* say UTC)
> - `true` & `false` or truthy & falsey? (if option 1)
> - Working or Livin' For The Weekend?

Comment: 1) option 2 is less trivial and so Peter Taylor *may* not downvote / 2) Local times, not UTC / 3) truthy & falsey if you choose option 1 / 4) Working For The Weekend

Comment: In my opinion this is far too trivial to be interesting.  I feel in general time based questions are pretty boring. I don't feel it provides anything that hasn't been covered extensively by other date/time questions.

Answer (score 0):

What could I add to improve this post? I have some questions that are inside of brackets.

## Introduction

A farmer needs help calculating the least time it will take him to pick his fruit each day.

## Challenge

- This farmer has `X` orchards.
- Each orchard has `Y` [is `Y` the correct variable to use here? does it matter?] fruits in it. If the orchard has no fruits, then it will contain the string "none".
- The farmer has a list, this list contains the fruit he must pick.
- The farmer will only go down the list **in order**
- You must calculate how long it will take the farmer to pick his fruit on each day.

#### More on the orchards

- All of the orchards are in a line.
- Each orchard is exactly `1` unit [should I say unit or kilometer?] away from the next and previous one.
- The farmer can go up and down the line, but may not jump from one orchard to another

## Input and Output

You will receive an input in the following format:

```
X
*string*
*string*
*string* *string* *string* *string*
*string*
//ect.
Y
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
//ect.
```

`X` is the number of orchards

- Everything after `X` and before `Y` is an orchard containing a/some string(s), each string is a different fruit in that orchard.

`Y` is the number of days that the farmer must gather fruit.

- Each day consists of two strings that are different fruits.
- You must find what orchard these strings are in and calculate the difference.

#### Input Rules:

1. Each fruit name string will be one word with **no spaces**
2. [Should I add more here? if so, what should I add?]

#### Real Example

Still confused? Maybe this will clear it up:

Input

```
6 

none

apple

orange pear pear

none

orange lemon pumpkin

pumpkin lettuce flowers peas

4

peas lettuce 

apple orange 

apple pumpkin 

flowers orange
```

output: `[ 0, 1, 3, 1 ]`

#### Explanation

Input:

- `6` the number of orchards
- A set of `6` orchards containing fruit, each orchard on a new line.
- `4` the number of days on the farmers list.
- A set of `4` fruits to compare, each pair of fruits is on a new line.

Output:

- Output an array of the differences between each set of fruits.
- The difference between peas and lettuce is `0`, because they are in the same orchard.
- The difference between apples and oranges is `1` because they are one orchard apart.
- The difference between apples and pumpkins is `3` Because they are three orchards apart.
- The difference between flowers and oranges is `1` because they are one orchard apart.

---

Annotated input/output

```
6 orchards 

a none

b apple

c orange pear pear

d none

e orange lemon pumpkin

f pumpkin lettuce flowers peas

--

4 fruits

peas lettuce 0

apple orange 1

apple pumpkin 3

flower orange 1

--

output: [ 0, 1, 3, 1 ]
```

Comment: I would only use the name *y* one time, as using it for two different things makes this a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

## Grouped Keyboard Scores

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

[image: color board]

In the above graphic, one can see 12 distinct color groups, which roughly correspond to columns on a keyboard. The following is a plaintext representation of which characters occur in each group.

```
Group 1:  ~` \n\t
Group 2:  !1QqAaZz
Group 3:  @2WwSsXx
Group 4:  #3EeDdCc
Group 5:  $4RrFfVv
Group 6:  %5TtGgBb
Group 7:  ^6YyHhNn
Group 8:  &7UuJjMm
Group 9:  *8IiKk<,
Group 10: (9OoLl>.
Group 11: )0Pp:;?/
Group 12: _-{["'+=}]|\
```

**Challenge:** Sort characters in the input according to their position in the aforementioned table. For input `"Hello, World!"`, the output would be `" !WedrH,llool"`. The relative order of characters within the same group does not matter, so the output `" !WderH,llloo"` is just as acceptable.

**Scoring:** Let **P** be the product of the number of characters in each non-empty section. Let **S** be the number of sections your program uses. Then, your score is **P** × **S**.

For example, the program `QAZ` would have a score of `3`, and `QWERTY` would have a score of `6`. `12321` would have a score of `12`. **The lowest such score wins.**

Here is a code snippet for scoring your submission:

```js
var sections = [
    "`~\t\n ",
    "!1QqAaZz",
    "@2WwSsXx",
    "#3EeDdCc",
    "$4RrFfVv",
    "%5TtGgBb",
    "^6YyHhNn",
    "&7UuJjMm",
    "*8IiKk<,",
    "(9OoLl>.",
    ")0Pp:;?/",
    "_-{[\"'+=}]|\\"
];

function getSection(chr){
    for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
        if(sections[i].indexOf(chr) >= 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function score(program){
    // group by sections
    var sectionHolder = [];
    var foundSections = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < program.length; i++){
        var chr = program[i];
        var index = getSection(chr);
        if(index < 0)
            return "n/a\nInvalid character: " + chr;
        
        if(!sectionHolder[index])
            sectionHolder[index] = [];
        
        sectionHolder[index].push(chr);
        
        if(foundSections.indexOf(index) < 0)
            foundSections.push(index);
    }
    
    var S = foundSections.length;
    var P = foundSections.map(function(e){
        return sectionHolder[e].length;
    }).reduce(function(a, c){
        return a * c;
    }, 1);;
    
    return S * P;
}
var output, code;
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    code = document.getElementById("code");
});
function update(){
    output.innerHTML = "";
    output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        "Score = " + score(code.value)
    ));
}
```

```css
* { font-family: Consolas, monospace; }
#output { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<textarea id="code" oninput="update();"></textarea>

<div id="output"></div>
```

### Test cases

Note: `␉` represents a tab and `␤` represents a newline.

```
 "input" => "output"

 "Hello, World!" => " !WedrH,llool"
 "Grouped Keyboard Scoring" => "  aSededcrrrGbgynuKiooop"
 "QWERTYUIOPqwertyuiop" => "QqWwEeRrTtYyUuIiOoPp"
 "2017 + 42 = something" => "    122se4tghn7mio0+="
 "Tab␉ulator" => "␉aarTbtulo"
 "Hello␤World" => "␤WedrHllool"
```

Comment: Should group one be: ~` \n\t?

Comment: @carusocomputing Yes, indeed

Answer (score 0):

## Bastion Breach

Stolen [with permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ue57.png) from the minigame with the same title from [Angels with Scaly Wings](http://store.steampowered.com/app/571880/Angels_with_Scaly_Wings/)

### Introduction and rules

- There are two players
- Both players receive a suit of cards (2-9, ace and face cards) and another is randomly shuffled into a public zone.
- The players then proceed to choose one of the cards in their hand to bid for the card. Once they've used a card, it can't be used again.
- The owner of the card with the highest value then gets a point.
- If the highest scoring card was in the middle or if the value of the highest cards is equal, nobody gets a point. That point then goes onto the next round and is awarded to the winner of that round.
- The ace is special: it wins against a face card, ties with another ace, and loses against a number card. Effectively the scoring system is reversed for the ace card.
- The player with the most points at the end of the game wins.

### Input/Output format for bots:

At the beginning of each round, your bot will be called as a whole program and will receive input in the form `cards-in-middle your-played-cards opponents-played-cards` as command line arguments.

Example: `23456789JKQA 24 56` - The cards in the middle are `23456789JKQA`, your played cards are `24` and your opponents are `56`. Your opponent won both of the previous games and what you're bidding for is the card `4`.

You will output a single character representing a card that you haven't already played. If it is invalid or you've already played it, you automatically forfeit the round. Valid outputs are the following characters: `23456789JQKA`

### Example scoring

```
Middle card: 2
Bot 1 card: 4
Bot 2 card: 5
Winner: Bot 2
----
Middle card: Q
Bot 1 card: K
Bot 2 card: 5
Winner: Bot 1
----
Middle card: Q
Bot 1 card: K
Bot 2 card: A
Winner: Bot 2
----
Middle card: Q
Bot 1 card: 6
Bot 2 card: 5
Winner: None, next round scores another point
----
Middle card: A
Bot 1 card: 2
Bot 2 card: J
Winner: Bot 1
----
Middle card: 5
Bot 1 card: K
Bot 2 card: 5
Winner: Bot 1
----
Middle card: 5
Bot 1 card: 2
Bot 2 card: 5
Winner: None, next round scores another point
----
Middle card: A
Bot 1 card: 9
Bot 2 card: J
Winner: None, next round scores another point
```

Scoring for regular cards: `23456789JQK`

Scoring for the ace:

```
wins: JQK
draw: A
lose: 23456789
```

### Submission

You should write your entry as

> Bot Name, Language
>
> ```
> Insert
> Code
> Here
> ```
>
> Explanation/Random stuff here

### Running the tournament yourself

The controller is available here (Sandbox: Not written yet). It can be ran with `python3 controller.py` or `python controller.py` depending on your path. It expects all the bots to be in the `bots` directory. You can get all the bots already entered with `python get_answers.py` or `python3 get_answers.py`

### Other rules and information

- Bots are not allowed to use file storage.
- The competition will be [Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament), all bots will play against all others and they will be ranked by the number of other bots they've won against.

  - A loss counts as nothing
  - A draw counts as one point
  - A win counts as two points
- The bot with the most points wins the game.
- The bot that wins the final game, to be ran on  wins the tournament.

#### Sandbox notes:

- I have yet to create a controller for this though I'll probably be basing it off the one I did for the [cake cutting contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/the-cake-cutting-contest)
- I hope I've explained it well enough, it's a simple game and I want the barrier for entry as low as possible. I've tried fixing what I believe went wrong with the GOL challenge and feel that KOTHs work better when they have lots of bots.
- I have permission to post this from the developer of the game in question, see first line.
- Feedback on readability is very much appreciated and welcome

Comment: "*Both players receive a suit of cards (2-9, ace and face cards) and another is randomly shuffled into a public zone. The players then proceed to choose one of the cards in their hand to bid for the card.*" Which card? Reverse engineering from the example, I *think* that what's meant is that the third suit is uniformly shuffled and dealt face up in a line, such that both players can see the entire sequence of auctions, and then the cards are auctioned off one by one from left to right. Future references to "*the middle*" are presumably references to the same "*public zone*"?

Comment: "*The ace is special: it wins against a face card, ties with another ace, and loses against a number card.*" Unless I'm missing something, there's nothing *special* there: just an overcomplicated abstraction. On the basis of KISS I would suggest making the cards be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11` or `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M`.

Comment: The ace card is different in that it's scored in reverse compared to the other cards. And your first comment is correct, how would you suggest rewording for it to be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

## Studio 54

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[Studio 54](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_54) was a famous nightclub in Manhattan. The club is referenced in the [Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama) episode [Rebirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebirth_(Futurama)#Cultural_references) in which the crew visits a nightclub called Studio 1<sup>2</sup>2<sup>1</sup>3<sup>3</sup>. The mathematical expression 1<sup>2</sup>2<sup>1</sup>3<sup>3</sup> evaluates to **(1 x 1) x (2) x (3 x 3 x 3) = 1 x 2 x 27 = 54**.

### Challenge

Determine whether a positive integer is a "studio number." We define a studio number to be a number **n** that can be expressed as the product of a set of distinct positive integers that does not include **n**, each of which is raised to the power of one of the numbers in the set. Or, more mathematically:

[image: Studio Numbers]

You should have a consistent output value for "is a studio number" and "is not a studio number," and nothing else.

### Test cases

These are inexhaustive lists and are just meant for basic ad-hoc testing.

Studio numbers:

```
4
12
16
18
52
54
64
68
72
88
96
```

Not studio numbers:

```
1
2
9
10
11
42
53
55
69
77
87
90
```

Computed by [this script](https://tio.run/##bZLBboMwDIbvfQpfJgWG2rJpl0r0uCfYfUpJ2CwFByVmAk17dkZooFA1t9i/f3@O0/T8bel1GCpna0DWjq01HrBurGNotKtbloyW/O6xpLT1BSlKdkpX4NuL1@yFSU47GE9lHSAggZP0pYXRNKbgGfKYnzXXuiBcewqTAa6U4fSojYr6a8/GWdWWvPS0LUMB@dK/C7bm5hLyaQHdFHCaW0chdjVT@IPeOi9o4/ab/z2a52XkIxYEaQr7t/vBsAKCp1FfFHDcTjG67qVSApOHYYLDAWLunhD9p@dWoV0QA1QpSaGSrAPcvIXVMFus@cmWqgTOQFvE0hIjtXpdJ6kXc20tG2FkfVESuqw/QZemfXbjyKYPlCRheJoQwz3QrT/WiuBuz3HsDxcJ4v1dGq@HYEe3NeQZ5MdjNGjctJJs81DJ8A8).

### Sandbox

I'm going off of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12307/31625) for the two consistent outputs, but I'm not really sold either way. I could also change the requirements to be to output the "studio" representation of the number.

Does the math-y bit help? Could I make the studio number definition clearer?

I've been unable to find any "nice" properties of these numbers that allow for methods besides brute force. Would this still be interesting enough to golf? I could also add a "reasonable time" limit that would enforce some non-naive code to reject bad attempts, but I'm not sure that's much better.

The studio numbers do not appear to be a sequence recorded on the OEIS.

Comment: You say "does include n", but I think you mean, "does not include n".

Comment: @Challenger5 Uhhh, whooops... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Only HeLlO WoRLd is allowed.

We are all familiar that "Hello World" is the 1st introductory program that most people learn when they first start to program. Then programmers go on to greater and better programs. But who says they have to go on to greater and better programs? What if all other programs were censored?

## Your Task:

Write a computer program that takes in standard input. If the standard input is any **case-insensitive** version of HeLlO WoRLd, do nothing. If the Standard input is anything other than a case insensitive HeLlO WoRLd, print an infinite loop of a HELLO WORLD matrix to the standard output.

To print an infinite HELLO-WORLD-Matrix, randomly sort the letters of "HELLO" and the letters of "WORLD", join the two words with a space as if you were saying HELLO WORLD, although you are probably saying  "HELLO DWROL", " OELLH LWODR" gibberish with an occasional "HELLO WORLD". Then just keep printing all this gibberish to the standard output.

```
ELHOL WRDLO     HOELL LDWRO     LOELH DLWRO     EOLHL DRLOW     LHELO OLRWD     

OLELH LODRW     EOHLL LWROD     LLOHE OWDRL     HLLEO OLRWD     LEHOL LOWDR  

OLLHE WROLD     OLEHL DLRWO     OHLEL OWDLR     LLHEO OWDRL     LLEHO ROLWD     

HELOL WLORD     HLOLE LWODR     LHOEL ODLWR     OLEHL DWORL     LLHEO OWDRL     

LHOLE WORDL     LOLHE WLODR     HLLOE WRODL     HOLLE LDORW     EOLHL WODLR  

ELOHL DRWLO     LHELO LRDWO     HLOEL RLDWO     LHOLE DOWLR     OLELH DOLWR     

OLLEH WORLD     LHLOE RWLDO     OELLH LWODR     LEHLO DOLRW     EOHLL DWRLO     

HELLO WORLD     LOLEH ODWRL     HOLLE WDLOR     LHEOL LORWD     LLOHE OLDWR     

OHLLE DRLOW     LOEHL LODWR     OHLLE ODRLW     HOLEL LWDRO     HOLEL DWROL  

ELOLH RWOLD     EOLHL WDLOR     LHOLE WRODL     HLLEO ODLRW     HLELO LDWOR     

HLELO WLDRO     HLLOE DRWLO     HOLEL OLWRD     OELHL WORDL     HOELL LDRWO     

LLEHO WORLD     OLELH DLOWR     OLHEL LDWRO     ELOLH DWROL     EHLLO WDLRO  

OLELH LDROW     LHEOL WORLD     OLEHL LWDRO     OELHL RWLOD     LEOLH RWOLD     

HLOLE DRLOW     LOELH RWLOD     LHELO LODWR     LLOHE LWDRO     LOEHL OWDLR     

LEHOL WORDL     OLEHL RWLDO     LOELH LOWDR     HEOLL LODRW     HLOLE RLODW  

LLEHO DWORL     LLOHE DWOLR     LLHEO RODWL     OLLEH DLWOR     LHEOL ORDWL     

HLEOL OWDRL     LELOH LDROW     HELLO LDWRO     HOELL ODWLR     OEHLL ROWDL     

EHOLL WRLDO     HLOLE WRLDO     LLHEO WDRLO     LOLEH OLDWR     OEHLL RLWDO  

OELHL DLORW     LLHEO RDWOL     HLLOE OLDRW     OLLHE LRODW     OELLH LDROW     

LEHOL LOWDR     LEHLO DRLOW     HOLEL WROLD     LHELO LORWD     EHLLO LWODR     

HLOLE OLRDW     LOLHE OLRWD     LOLHE DORWL     LOHEL WDLRO     OHELL RWOLD  

LEHLO RLWDO     HLEOL LWRDO     OELLH LWORD     HELLO LDROW     OLHLE LWDRO
```

There is actually only one "HELLO WORLD" amid all this gibberish

**Winning criterion**: shortest program in bytes.

Comment: What is an infinite loop of a HELLO WORLD matrix?

Comment: Actually, I think I would like to up the challenge and request that HELLO WORLDS be printed to the standard output in a tab deliminated string with the letters randomly sorted, so occassionally the standard output would get HELLO WORLD    HELLO WORLD ...

But it would mostly get  "EHLLO DWORL    HEOW LLROD ... etc.

Comment: I updated my HELLO WORLD INFINITE matrix problem and made it more difficult. You should check it out. Is there anyway that I can have the tab separation show up on the problem the same way it shows up on the edit tab?

Comment: You may want to say *"anagram of..."* instead of *"randomly sort the letters of..."*

Comment: Are there rules about the horizontal and vertical spacing of your matrix, and the number of helloworldoids per line? This needs to be explicitly specified or else explicitly left flexible.

Comment: What do you think would make the challenge the most fun?

Answer (score 0):

## Golfing a Busy Turing Machine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [turing-machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turing-machine) [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

### For the sandbox

This question is really hard, and the solution is restricted to one "language" – a 1-tape, 2-symbol Turing Machine. So I'm not sure if it belongs on PPCG. I've written up a basic description below, but can go into more detail if anyone is interested.

### Question

I recently came across a [paper](https://github.com/adamyedidia/parsimony/blob/master/tex/busybeaver/busybeaver.pdf) that explicitly presents a 7910-state 1-tape, 2-symbol Turing machine that cannot be proven to run forever in ZFC, assuming ZFC is consistent. It also cites codegolf.stackexchange.com!

The existence of this Turing machine proves that calculating BB(7910) is independent of ZFC.

So, we know that we can calculate up to at least BB(4), and definitely can't calculate BB(7910) and above.

Can you create a Turing Machine with under 7910 states that cannot be proven to run forever in ZFC?

The author designed two custom-purpose programming languages (Laconic and TMD) to create this Turing Machine. In order to improve upon his work, I imagine you could go one of three ways:

1. Optimize his algorithm in Laconic such that it encodes the interpreter or Friedman's mathematical statement (section 3.1) more tersely.
2. Optimize TMD so individual instructions are translated to fewer states.
3. Find a simpler statement whose truth implies the consistency of ZFC, and encode that instead of Friedman's statement.
4. Go another direction entirely!

### Winning criteria

The Turing Machine with the fewest number of states that cannot be proven to run forever in ZFC, wins. The length of the code you used to generate this Turing Machine is irrelevant.

You don't win if you compute BB(5), but you do get eternal fame.

Comment: There's currently a huge loophole in the question: you can just present a Turing machine that trivially halts, without violating any of the rules. Defining this unambiguously is going to be hard; the problem is that the submitter has to prove that the Turing machine always halts, but also prove that the Turing machine can't be proven to always halt, which is almost a contradiction (and only works because the first "prove" is subjective but the last objective; but how do you enforce a subjective criterion?). That said, I like the question and it'd be nice if it could be made to work.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the vast majority of PPCG users won't understand the question no matter how precisely you try to word it. That probably isn't a problem for the people who are interested in or are willing to learn computability theory, but expect a large number of wrong answers that misunderstand the question and have to be deleted.

Comment: @ais523 "Cannot be proven to run forever" is a subtle point – it's not that it doesn't run forever but that it's impossible to prove whether or not it does. If the submitter can prove that the Turing machine always halts, then it would not be a valid submission. Or if it were, would solve the halting problem. I should clarify to say "cannot be proven either to halt or to run forever." My big concern is your second comment, though. In any case, this post explains the main points in the paper, and is very accessible and worth reading independent of PPCG! http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725

Comment: Right, I think the correct framing of this problem is "produce a Turing machine that cannot be proven to halt and cannot be proven not to halt". (Of course, we know it won't halt in practice, because if it did, you could prove it halts by running it, but that should be left out of the framing of the question.) That makes it clearer what's going on to people who haven't seen the problem in question beforehand. I wonder if opening this up to other languages might not be interesting too: brainfuck, for example, is a good fit for this challenge. Things like Jelly probably aren't though.

Comment: @ais523 The way to construct a program like this is usually to say "this machine halts iff conjecture A is true" where conjecture A's truth implies the consistency of ZFC.

Comment: Opening up to other languages seems reasonable enough, especially as I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to write a brainfuck to 1-tape turing machine transpiler

Comment: I can tell you haven't read the discussion about this in the comments of two blog posts in Aaronson's blog, because Stefan O'Rear one-upped with a search for a contradiction in ZFC in about 1900 states. See https://github.com/sorear/metamath-turing-machines . NB https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79620/194 was also inspired by that discussion, although in a slightly different direction. See http://cheddarmonk.org/papers/laver.pdf for a 64-state machine which is not known to halt in ZFC, but is proven to halt assuming a rank-into-rank cardinal.

Comment: @PeterTaylor very cool, thanks! I generally try to steer clear of comment-reading on blogs, but I should probably make an exception for academic ones.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just noticed that the Laver paper is yours. Super impressive. I'd love to know if/when you ever end up publishing it

Comment: Any answer to this is also an answer to [Write a program whose nontermination is independent of Peano arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79470). Turing machine answers are welcome. (Though I’m not sure how we score those in bytes… perhaps the entropy measure (2n lg (4n + 1))/8?) Also (conjecturally) related: [Laver table computations and an algorithm that is not known to terminate in ZFC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79620).

Answer (score 0):

## Write an interpreter for XKCD's broken language

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

---

## Meta

- Is this a good idea?
- Is the point system good?

  - If so, are the point values good? I based them off of how difficult I imaged each part to be.

### Overview

Randall Munroe, author of the webcomic XKCD, posted a comic a while back about a joke programming language and how it gets types confused.

[Here's the comic in question](https://xkcd.com/1537/)

Your job is to write an interpreter for a slightly modified version of this language.

### Rules

- If your language supports it, it must be a live interpreter where all input lines start with `[#]>` (where # is the line number) and all outputs must start with `=>`.

  - If your language does not support it, you may substitute this with reading all the lines on the input and printing out each output on its own line, still starting with `=>`. Remember to keep track of line numbers.
- All commands must be usable in any order and with any parameters (within reason)
- Each command you implement correctly is worth the listed point value. See scoring to find your final score.

#### Integers plus numeric strings (1 point)

Given an int and a string containing a number (in that order) calculate the numeric sum of them, then return the result as a string with quotes surrounding it.

```
[1]> 2 + "2"
=> "4"
[2]> 6 + "13"
=> "19"
```

#### Numeric strings plus lists (1 point)

Given a numeric string and a list, append the numeric value to the list and return the list as a string.

```
[1]> "3" + []
=> "[3]"
[2]> "7" + [1,4]
=> "[1,4,7]"
```

#### Dividing by zero (1 point)

Any number divided by zero returns a NaN object. This does not have quotes around it.

```
[1]> 1/0
=> NaN
```

#### NaN plus integer (2 points)

Given a NaN object and an integer, pretend it's a string and increment the leading character, carrying over if needed. The result does not have quotes.

```
[1]> (5/0)+2
=> NaP
[2]> NaN+256
=> NbN
```

You do not need to use ASCII for this, any character set works, as long as it includes at minimum the 52 uppercase and lowercase letters.

You will never have to add a result from this to another integer. (For example, `NaP+4` is invalid)

#### String plus string (1 point)

Given two strings, remove swap the first and last quotes with single quotes and return the result.

```
[1]> ""+""
=> '"+"'
[2]> "Hello"+"world"
=> 'Hello"+"world'
```

#### List of integers plus integer (3 points)

Given a list of integers (or an empty list) and another integer, return True or False based on whether the new integer matches the linear pattern.

It will follow this rule:

If the list has 0 or 1 items, return True regardless (everything matches).
Determine the pattern of the list by subtracting every item by the item right before it. If the pattern is inconsistent, return False regardless (nothing matches).
Otherwise, check if the new integer matches the pattern. If it does, return True. If it doesn't, return False.

```
[1]> [1, 2, 3, 4] + 5
=> True
[2]> [5, 7, 9, 11] + 13
=> True
[3]> [6, 5, 4, 3] + 2
=> True
[4]> [2, 4, 6, 8] + 9
=> False
[5]> [1, 2, 1, 4] + 5
=> False
```

#### Range(a, b) (1 point)

With the Range function given two numbers, return a list of numbers from a to b.

```
[1]> Range(1, 5)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2]> Range(3, 6)
=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
[3]> Range(6, 4)
=> [6, 5, 4]
```

#### Plus integer (1 point)

Given simply "+" and an integer, return the line number plus the integer.

```
[1]> +2
=> 3
[2]> +2
=> 4
[3]> +1
=> 4
```

#### Single digit plus single digit (2 points)

Given two single digit integers `a` and `b`, replace all future instances of `a` in the output with `(a+b)%10` (where % means modulo, essentially wrap around if the result is more than 1 digit). Return Done. This effect is superficial and has no effect on math. This only affects output, not input.

```
[1]> 3+2
=> Done
[2]> Range(1, 6)
=> [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6]
[5]> 1+2
=> Done
[4]> Range(1, 6)
=> [3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

#### Floor (1 point)

Draw an ascii art floor with the number at the bottom. The specifications are 3 lines of only pipes, then a line with a pipe, 3 underscores, the number, and 3 underscores.

```
[1]> Floor(4.7)
=> |
=> |
=> |
=> |___4.7___
[2]> Floor(105.3)
=> |
=> |
=> |
=> |___105.3___
```

### Scoring

Add up the points you've earned. Your score is now calculated as `(15-points) * bytecount`. Lower is better.

### Notes

- You do not have to account for mixing functions. For example, `Range(Floor(2.3))` is invalid.
- Whitespace may be added or removed as is convenient.
- Double quotes or single quotes may be used as convenient (as long as you use the opposite for "String plus string")
- Any brackets may be used for lists, as long as it's consistent.
- A few commands were omitted from the original comic because I couldn't figure out a way to make it well specified.

Comment: Scoring is broken: it goes up when you implement more features, but down when you golf bytes off the program. Those should probably both aim in the same direction. Also, even if you change "multiply" to "divide", you're still only scoring on the average number of bytes per feature (which incentivizes only implementing one feature, the shortest). The normal fix is to divide the byte count by the square of the points from features, lower is better.

Comment: *If your language supports this, do that. If not, do this* is not a very good idea. Also, reading multiple lines and the `=>` prefix seems like it's just extra code for no good reason.

Comment: @ais523 Ah thanks for catching that. What I meant was, you take your point score and calculate (15-points)*bytes. If you get all of them, your score is simply your byte count. If you get a few of them, your score is larger accordingly. Lower is better.

Comment: @Okx The `=>` prefix is to keep with the style of the comic. And reading multiple lines is important because some of the commands affect things in the future, which you wouldn't see if you can't input multiple lines. I see what you mean though about *if this, that, if not, this*. Do you think the interactive approach is better or the non-interactive one?

Comment: Dupe? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52953/8478

Comment: @MartinEnder I would argue that is not a dupe. That question hopes to simulate the comic's output, without making it general. Return values to functions can be hardcoded. Mine has stricter specifications.

Answer (score 0):

## Call a library function

Given a single int32, a path to a Dynamic Link Library (.dll) or Shared Library (.so), and the name of a function, return the single int32 result of calling the function on the single int32.

#### Examples

On 64 bit Linux: `0` `/usr/lib64/libm-2.24.so` `fesetround` → `0`

On 64 bit Linux: `1` `/usr/lib64/libm-2.24.so` `fesetround` → `1`

On 32 bit Linux: `1023` `/usr/lib/libm-2.24.so` `fesetround` → `1`

On 32 bit Linux: `1024` `/usr/lib/libm-2.24.so` `fesetround` → `0`

On 64 bit Windows: `inp` `please\edit\filename.dll` `fname` → `out`

On 64 bit Windows: `inp` `please\edit\filename.dll` `fname` → `out`

Comment: **Please help me find a suitable DLL!**

Comment: This needs to specify that the function takes a single int32 as argument and returns a single int32.

Comment: @ais523 Thanks, done.

Comment: Where's the int32 in the Windows examples?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I need help with a dll that's commonly found on Windows.

Comment: It's worth noting in the testcases that although `libm` is very commonly seen on Linux, the exact file path tends to vary from distribution to distribution. (For example, it's different on Fedora and Ubuntu.)

Comment: @ais523 Can you edit the Linux samples to replace "Linux" with "Fedora" and "Ubuntu" and give the correct paths?

Comment: @Adám: Not easily, they frequently change as a result of the system being updated, and it depends on processor architecture (not just bit depth) and sometimes even configuration. Just tell people to find the path to their own `libm` library for the appropriate architecture. (Note that the situation on Windows is much worse, because it doesn't ship even standard DLLs like `libm` by default.)

Comment: @ais523 Just as plausible example, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

## What is the maximum number of backslashes (escape characters) required to mean one backslash?

If you want to use a regex to look for a backslash, you have to escape
that backslash, so that the character after it isn't escaped instead.
But if you then have to store this regex in a string (in a c-style
language, for instance), you need to double the number of backslashes,
so that a regex string to match \stuff\ would need to be
"\\\\stu(f+)\\\\" (and I had to further double the backslashes
to post it in StackOverflow, but that isn't executable so doesn't
count).

In your answer, explain the language and the (reasonable) situation,
from either real or made-up business needs, and the answer with the
most backslashes (per final, output backslash) will get upvoted
(permanently) and accepted (until a better one comes along). If using
AutoHotKey or another language that has a different escape character
(for instance, `), then instances of that character will count
instead of backslashes.

This question is not how many backslashes *could* you use in some
esoteric code-golfing language to eventually calculate to a backslash,
otherwise I don't think there would be an upper limit. This instead is
about feasible scenarios that **force** you to use a lot of
backslashes.

Comment: I feel as though this simply devolves into finding as many languages as possible that have something like `eval`. You can't enforce "reasonableness" as it isn't objective. Sorry, but I don't think this kind of challenge is a good fit for our site. But thank you for using the sandbox!

Answer (score 0):

## Counting from `0` - `100`

I posted this question, but it was not taken very well, so I wanted to put it through the sandbox and get some feedback/help before re-posting.

## Challenge

Output all numbers from `0`-`100`. Without using any of your languages **built in loops**.

#### Loops that are not allowed

This list contains, **but is not limited to**

- For loops
- While loops
- Do While loops
- Goto Statment
- In Range

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution in bytes wins
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You may use functions as well as programs

Comment: I really don't think this is a good idea for a challenge. It would either be builtins, like [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QwCDo/38A "Jelly – Try It Online") in Jelly, or printing literal strings, with *maybe* some clever compression.

Comment: Ok, I will leave it here in the sandbox incase anyone else thinks that they have a way to make it better. But I will not post it.

Comment: @Christian [Definitely golfable too.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5qD//wE)

Comment: Also [the Python answer](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6soMS89VcPQwFBT8/9/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: "*but is not limited to*" - I think you're going to need to be more explicit than that. Does array mapping count as a loop, for example?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I actually had that ready to post when this challenge was posted in PPCG, but it was deleted before I had the chance to. I was just too lazy to look up the atom list when commenting on this post :P

Comment: "Without loops in your code" is a non-observable requirement. I don't think there is a good way to do what you want at all, since there are so many ways to "loop" that you can't possibly define them all. Take [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8rWkCu1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRKNK07pK29bQWknL0MBA8/9/AA) for example.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/8478) is what Fry is referring to with "non-observable requirement". In general imposing restrictions on which *features* answers can use is highly problematic. a) There are many many languages that don't have to constructs you explicitly disallow, but which may have similar constructs which aren't in the spirit of the restriction either. But b) "not limited to" doesn't fly because who is to decide whether any given construct is a loop or not? There are even languages where you can write loops without any specific syntax element for them.

Comment: In general, if you find yourself having to impose explicit restrictions on the allowed *approaches* to a challenge, it's often a sign that it's not a great idea in the first place. I assume this is why the challenge wasn't received well in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

### Data exfiltration

Frenzy in the frequency domain.

### Summary of the challenge

You must find a way to broadcast a ten-character password through a lossy communication channel and recover the password on the other side.
To achieve this you must write two programs. The first program will receive the password as input and encode it as output data for the channel, the second program has to decode the output of the channel back to the password.

#### Some background

In signal processing theory, many problems are usually dealt with by converting a signal from the time domain to the so-called [frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain), a trick that relies on the fact that any function can be written as an infinite series of sine waves. Signals can be converted into this domain using a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). This transform is lossless, and the resulting signal can be converted back into the time domain using the inverse Fourier transform. The frequency domain has some interesting properties, as the actual values of the signal in it represent the amplitude and phase of different frequencies in the original signal.

A special case exists for when the signal exists out of equally spaced sampled points, called the discrete-time Fourier transform. To perform this transform the [fast fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm is commonly used. Given a signal of N samples spaced with dt spacing, it will convert it into a signal containing N frequency bins which are each 1/(N*dt) apart.

#### Channel definition

The communication channel requires 256 unsigned bytes data as input, and returns 256 unsigned bytes data as output. If the input values are centered around zero and interpreted as data samples on regular intervals, then the output values represent the amplitude of the signal in the frequency domain scaled to use the range 0 to 255, calculated using a discrete fourier transform. The channel is lossy as it only transfers the amplitude of each frequency, not the phase.

It can be simulated using the following python 3 script:

```
import cmath
def channel():
    # amount of input and output values
    l=256
    # read the input values from standard input as newline separated integers and center them around zero
    n=list(map(lambda: min(255, max(0, int(raw_input())))-127.5, range(l)))
    # perform a discrete fourier transform
    v=[sum(v*cmath.exp(-2.0j*cmath.pi*t*k/l)for t,v in enumerate(n))/l for k in range(l)]
    # remove artifacts due to the Nyquist limit
    v[1:128]=map(lambda n:n*2,v[1:128])
    v[129:]=[.0]*127
    # return the scaled magnitude of each frequency bin
    for i in v:print(int(round(abs(i)*cmath.pi/2)))
```

#### Input/Output

The password is randomly generated using only using visible ASCII characters (0x20 up to and including 0x7E) and is 10 characters long.

Inputting the password to the encoder, communicating it to the channel, receiving data from the channel and communicating the decoded password should all follow the [default input/output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). The password must be decoded only from data received from the channel, no side-channels are allowed.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), where the score is calculated by adding the length of both the encoder and decoder program. For each language, the shortest entry in bytes wins.

### Meta

- Is the challenge clear
- Is the difficulty okay
- Anything else?

Tags:
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I feel like the background could use some work. I don't think someone unfamiliar with the FFT would know things like how it is periodic in time and in frequency, or that you could use and inverse DFT formula, barring calculation inaccuracies. Your description of the channel largely requires that people are already familiar with this, or that they understand python well. The penalties are largely pointless, it only really serves to make people not want to answer your question. The question is not too hard, but I think as it is it isn't accessible to people who haven't learned this already.

Comment: "Must output to standard output" is the sort of restriction which 90% of languages don't care about and the other 10% will require crazy amounts of boilerplate to accomplish, rather detracting from the rest of the challenge. I recommend that you link to [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/62131) to define legal forms of input and output, unless you have a good reason not to. Additionally, penalising builtins with character penalties doesn't really work because the size of the penalty differs from language to language (and those penalties are prohibitively large in most).

Comment: I've changed the input/output rules and removed the penalties in accordance with your comments. However I'm not sure how to improve the background, as explaining all the interesting tricks you can do with frequency domain manipulation would require significantly more explanation than possible (or interesting for most people) in a challenge. If people really want to learn about the details of it, the background section offers a few links that explain it much better than I could myself.

Answer (score 0):

### OCR

[test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

In this challenge you will attempt to write a program to perform OCR in the fewest bytes possible. The tests are linked below, the only data that your program receives is the contents of the image, you may not rely on file name, timestamp, or other metadata, additionally you may not query any external source such as the internet or dispatch an independent program to outsource the task of OCR.

### Spec

Given a hand written word in in image of 80px in height. Output the word. words will consist of lowercase latin letters:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

### Scoring

Given the test cases, your score is a percent of the words you have gotten correct. No partial credit.

---

Tests cases:

TODO

Comment: The scoring doesn't seem to be affected by the length of the code. Should the specification `in the fewest bytes possible` be there?

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28207/194). I think this gives a good example of how to do an OCR question well, but it also demonstrates that they're not a good fit for the site. It uses a standard database rather than home-made test cases, and tries to model the standard approach of training set and test set to prevent overfitting, but that standard approach isn't really compatible with our definition of objective scoring, because only the OP knows what the test set is.

Answer (score 0):

## Rotational Anagrams

Given, for lack of a better word, *an anagram cube* `c` with `n` *rings* and a *word* `w`, output whether or not you can rotate the individual sections to make `w` appear across the middle.

## Constraints

- The letters that can appear are all printable ASCII characters EXCEPT for newlines.

  - All three characters that make up the rings can appear (`|-+`).
- Your program should work for cubes of any size, though the maximum I expect you to test is my biggest case (this means that if your code won't finish for `n=22` on TIO, I don't care).
- Your only input should be the ASCII-art `c` and the word `w`.
- Your only output is one of two distinct values for `true/false`, which are arbitrary.
- You can assume the input is well-formed, and output **anything** for bad input.

## Examples

Example cube with `n=3` and `w='AXMOZC'`:

```
+----A----+
| +--Y--+ |
| | +N+ | |
B X M O Z D
| | +P+ | |
| +--W--+ |
+----C----+
```

Rotate the outer wheel once coutner clockwise:

```
+----D----+
| +--Y--+ |
| | +N+ | |
A X M O Z C
| | +P+ | |
| +--W--+ |
+----B----+
```

Ding-ding! A match, so we can output truthy for this, but for `AXMOYC` there is no rotation that allows that combination, so it would return falsy. (X and Y are not adjacent on the ring, which means they can't appear at the same time.

---

Here's a small cube of `n=2`:

```
+--G--+
| +P+ |
P C P G
| +C+ |
+--P--+
```

For an input `w=PPCG|GPCP|PCPG|GCPP` this returns true, everything else is false. So you can start to see that the possible keyspace of answers is always `n**2`, so... hint hint.

---

Here's the big honkin' example that took me a minute to piece up.

```
+----------1----------+
| +--------O--------+ |
| | +------5------+ | |
| | | +----E----+ | | |
| | | | +-----+ | | | |
| | | | | +G+ | | | | |
C 3 D E - B O L L I 4 G
| | | | | +O+ | | | | |
| | | | +--W--+ | | | |
| | | +----F----+ | | |
| | +------6------+ | |
| +--------N--------+ |
+----------2----------+
```

And, amongst many other strings, for `w=CODE-GOLFING|CODE-BOWLING` you should return true.

---

This is [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing), if you're on my front lawn the third Tuesday of next month in a batman costume doing unspeakable things to my sprinkler system, you've won.

Comment: Is this meant to be a challenge about parsing the input format? If so (and it seems to be), you probably want [tag:parsing]. Also, is there a need to verify the format, or can programs assume it's correct?

Comment: @ais523 I feel like there's enoguh challenge in the parsing, and that will allow some unique interesting choices to extrapolate out the wanted symbols. You don't have to handle invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

## List My Factors!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

### Introduction

Given an algebraic expression as input, list all the factors of it. A factor of an algebraic expression is any algebraic expression (or simply a numerical expression, sometimes) that evenly divides it. A factor can only be an integer or an algebraic expression consisting of integers and variables.

---

### Rules

- The algebraic expression will contain `*` to denote multiplication.
- The algebraic expression will only contain integer constants and coefficients.
- The algebraic expression will contain `^` to denote exponentiation.
- The algebraic expression will only contain positive constants, coefficients and variables.
- Your program should output only the positive factors.
- The algebraic expression will not contain negative exponents.
- You must not use any built-in to accomplish this.
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1146#1146) apply.

---

### Examples

The algebraic expression `5*x^2` has the following factors:

1. `5`
2. `x`
3. `x^2`
4. `5*x^2`
5. `5*x`
6. `1`

The algebraic expression `10*(x-y)^2` has the following factors:

1. `10`
2. `5`
3. `2`
4. `1`
5. `(x-y)`
6. `(x-y)^2` or `x^2 + y^2 - 2*x*y`
7. `2*(x-y)^2` or `2*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*x*y)` or `2*x^2 + 2*y^2 - 4*x*y`
8. `5*(x-y)^2` or `5*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*x*y)` or `5*x^2 + 5*y^2 - 10*x*y`
9. `10*(x-y)^2` or `10*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*x*y)` or `10*x^2 + 10*y^2 - 20*x*y`.
10. `10*(x-y)` or `10*x - 10*y`
11. `2*(x-y)` or `2*x - 2*y`
12. `5*(x-y)` or `5*x - 5*y`

The algebraic expression `x^2 - y^2` has the following factors:

1. `1`
2. `x-y`
3. `x+y`
4. `x^2 - y^2`

---

### Input

Your program may take the input in any way except assuming it to be present in a predefined variable. Reading from file, input box, modal window, command line etc. is allowed. Taking input as function argument is allowed as well.

---

### Output

Your program should output a list of factors of the given input as a collection data type (such as array) or as a separator-separated String.

Your program may output in any way except writing the output to a variable. Writing to file, screen, modal window, command line etc. is allowed. Outputting using function `return` is allowed as well.

---

### Test Cases

```
Input               Output

5*x^2               [5*x^2, 5, 1, 5*x, x, x^2]
10*x^2              [10*x^2, 10, 5, 2, 1, 10*x, 5*x, 2*x, x, 5*x^2, 2*x^2, x^2]
10*(x-y)^2          [10*(x-y)^2, 10, 2, 5, 1, 10*(x-y), 5*(x-y), 2*(x-y), (x-y), (x-y)^2, 2*(x-y)^2, 5*(x-y)^2]
x^2 - y^2           [x^2 - y^2, x+y, x-y, 1]
```

---

### Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

---

### Sandbox

1. <strike>Should I allow negative constants and coefficients?</strike> Answer : No
2. Should I allow variable exponents?
3. Is there any mistake in Examples and Test Cases?
4. How long should I let this challenge be here?
5. Any problem with the Input/Output Rules?
6. Should I allow built-in to accomplish the task?
7. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Would `x^2-y^2` be a valid input?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes .

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Comment: The rules should mention that addition and subtraction are allowed; they currently don't. I'm wondering whether this challenge would be more interesting if you had to find the decomposition into "prime" (i.e. irreducible) factors, rather than just all factors, though; the two are similar tasks but the latter is more interesting and easier to read the results of. As for question 4, just leave the challenge up indefinitely; time limits on challenges are a bad idea if they're at all avoidable, as many people enjoy solving older challenges.

Comment: @LeakyNun 1, x-y, x+y, x^2-y^2

Comment: It seems this challenge is more about parsing/pretty printing than about factoring. (The integers allow for brute forcing.) I'd recommend allowing for more flexible input and output, otherwise this is going to be trivial to write a competitive submission for some languanges with CAS but almost impossible for other languages.

Comment: @ais523 I've added what LeakyNun asked to the challenge. Better?

Comment: @flawr I don't understand what you mean with your first comment. To your second point : Good point, I'll edit

Comment: @flawr Edited .

Comment: 1. The examples now contradict the spec's limitations on input. 2. What is a *positive factor*? Is it a factor with only positive coefficients? 3. What are the factors of `x^x`? 4. If this is fundamentally "*factor a multivariate polynomial*", I think there may be one or two questions along those lines already in the sandbox. The univariate case [has been done on main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38513/194).

Comment: Before I forget, a nice (or nasty) illustration of the relevance of my question 2: `x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 8 = (x + 2)(x^2 - x + 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Home on the Range [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## Challenge

Given a range `[0,n)` that has been shuffled, return the index of each element of the range.

## Examples

```
[1, 2, 0] -> [2, 0, 1]
```

This is the range `[0, 3)` after being shuffled. The element at index `0` in the result is `2` because, in the input, `0` is at index `2`. Likewise, the `0` in the output is the index of the `1` in the input, and the `1` is the index of `2`.

```
[1, 0, 2] -> [1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 1, 3] -> [0, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 0, 1, 3] -> [1, 2, 0, 3]
[3, 2, 0, 1] -> [2, 3, 1, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 0, 1] -> [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 0, 3] -> [3, 0, 1, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 0, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 0, 3, 1]
```

## Bonus

I will award a +100 bounty to the first person to design and explain an algorithm that solves this problem using `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

## Sandbox

- I think my explanation was rather poor. How can I make this more clear?
- Is this a dupe?
- Is the bonus a good idea? (I really want to hear the answer because I don't know if this is even possible!)

Comment: Why `[4, 3, 2, 0, 1] -> [3, 4, 1, 2, 0]` not `-> [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: Oh, and do realize that this is what [`/:` in J does](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/slashco), which makes [this](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19B30rBUMFAwYgLxjMA8o0UjJH4RkARBN8IrALBN4aIwPkmGCIg80yAIshmgPkKhv//AwA) a 2-byte solution.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh, well that sucks /:

Comment: @LeakyNun Typo. Thanks! I've never used J so I didn't realize there would be a builtin for it /: maybe I could convert this into a "best-algorithm" question?

Comment: Essentially https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95838/194 ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, essentially. And I think it's a one-byte solution in Jelly: `Ụ`.

Comment: @musicman523 And it is a one-byter in Dyalog APL as well

Comment: I could do one of three things: post it anyway to allow non-golfing languages to compete, make it a best-algorithm question instead, or delete it entirely. What do you all think?

Comment: I think that a) there's very little point in posting something which will be closed as a dupe; b) best-algorithm is hard to judge when built-ins do the job for you but their implementation might be closed or vary between versions; c) the bonus is pretty trivial provided that you specify that the code should modify the supplied array, and impossible otherwise.

Comment: @PeterTaylor how can you do it, modifying the original array?

Comment: Cycle by cycle, using `~` (bitwise not) as a flag to indicate which cycles have already been visited.

Comment: What happens if the entire array is a cycle? How do you process it with O(1) memory?

Comment: Bounty for O(n) time and O(1) space? But... but it's code golf.

Comment: @NeilA. don't worry this isn't going to be posted, at least not as-is

Answer (score 0):

## Find the maximum number of coprimes in a set

Inspired by a recent question on Math.stackexchange.com, which I can't find anymore.

### The challenge

Exactly what it says on the tin. You are given a set of integers and you have to create a program (according to the default definitions on meta) that outputs the size of the biggest subset that shares no divisors except for 1.

### Input

A set of nonzero positive integers of length >= 2. You can take this input as per the defaults in meta.

### Output

Output, print or return  the size of the subset of the input that does not share any divisors except for one.

### Testcases

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
7

1 3
1

2 3 5 7 9
4

2 3 5 7 11 13
6
```

Comment: 1. The second test case is wrong: it should give `2`. 2. What does it mean for a subset to share a divisor? Perhaps "*the biggest subset such that no two of its elements share a divisor greater than 1*". 3. In all of the test cases, it suffices to count the elements which are either 1 or prime. The question needs test cases for which that isn't sufficient. It might be nice to encode some classic graphs like Petersen's.

Answer (score 0):

### Golf a program whose behavior is independent from Peano arithmetic

Your task is to write a program that doesn't take any input, and whose termination cannot be proved or disproved inside Peano arithmetic. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest byte count wins!

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- Shortest by count wins
- You can assume that your program runs in a machine with an unlimited amount of memory.

## Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

---

## Questions for meta

- Is this a good challenge?
- Is it a duplicate?
- I think the same question with a behavior independent of ZF set theory might be interesting as well (see [this link](http://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf) for instance), but will attract very different answers; should I post it as a separate challenge?
- What can be improved? Are the tags ok?

Comment: [Current sandbox post that's fairly close to this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12974/62131). There might be two challenges in this space, but maybe just one; perhaps you could give feedback on the other post?

Comment: It seems like the other sandbox post is pretty limited to Turing machines only, whereas this one allows any programming language, so I think the two will attract quite different answers. Secondly, I believe restricting to Peano arithmetic instead of ZF will make solutions that are simpler, so I believe the two challenges are still quite different (but I'd like input from others on this as well).

Comment: Is this the same as [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79470/20260)?

Comment: @xnor it is the same indeed, so I guess I should instead go for independent of ZF. This makes it closer to the other sandbox proposal, but I still think allowing any programming language makes the challenge quite different from a Turing machine-only one.

Comment: See also: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=aaronson

Comment: If a program’s behavior is independent of ZF or ZFC, it’s also independent of PA, so I’d be happy to see such programs posted on the existing challenge, unless it starts getting so many answers that they get drowned out (current trends suggest that’s unlikely ☹).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg true, it looks like people are not that interested in this kind of challenges :( The point for having two separate challenges was because ZF/ZFC-independent answers might be a lot more complicated than PA ones.

Comment: @nore Do you know of any simple answers to the PA challenge? I don’t think my PA answer is notably simpler than a ZFC version would be.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I tried to find statements that are easy to check and that are independent of PA, but the simplest I have been able to find is still the ZF-independent one used in the busy beaver paper.

Answer (score 0):

**Iterate over all sets**

(This question needs fixing so that the output size is not too large)

Consider all possible pairs of sets of integers (can have positive, negative and zero values) `A` and `B` such  that `|A| = |B| = 7`.  Define the set `T_{A,B} = {a * b | a in A, B in B}`.

The challenge is to iterate over all pairs of sets `A` and `B` so that `|T_{A,B}| < 19` and the largest absolute value of an integer in `A` or `B` is at most `128`.  As an example of one such pair of sets, `A = B = {2^i | for i in {1,...,7}}`.

**What should my code output?**

Your code should output the pairs of sets `A, B` along with `|T_{A,B}|`.

For example:

```
A = {2,4,8,16,32,64,128}, B = {2,4,8,16,32,64,128}, |T_{A,B}| = 13.
```

**Running time**

I don't care how long your code takes to run except you must run your answer to completion before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Code golf the Fast growing hierarchy (fgh)

if your not familiar with the fgh you migth want to check out this explantion:  [Large Numbers, Part 3: Functions and Ordinals](http://archive.is/QffmL)

and these value aproximations: [Fast growing hierarchy Approximations](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Approximations)

the goal this code golf is to golf the following functions:

- the exact value of f<sub>ω</sub>(x) this means you can't golf the ackermann function
- the growth rate of f<sub>ω2</sub>(x)
- the growth rate of f<sub>ω<sup>2</sup></sub>(x)

In any language of your chose.

This is a code golf so the smallest program that defines each of these functions wins (**Note**:the functions are allowed to call each other).

It is also allowed to ask for an input x and output the 3 function values in any order.

## Tags

[busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver),[growth-rate-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growth-rate-golf),[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion)

## Sandbox notes

I'm not sure on which functions should be the target but these functions seem challenging yet golf-able in less than 150 bytes.

Upon closer inspection I realized that f<sub>ω<sup>2</sup></sub>(x) is probably to easy since it can be golfed with something like:

```
f(x,a...) {
    for i in range(a.length) {
        if(a[i] != 0) { //first non zero
            Arrays.fill(a, 0, i, x); //replace 0's with x
            a[i]--; //decrement a[i]
            return f^x(x,a);
        }
    }
    //all zeros
    return x+1;
}
```

`f(x,n)` > f<sub>n</sub>(x)

`f(x,0,n)` > f<sub>ωn</sub>(x)

`f(x,0,0,n)` > f<sub>ω^n</sub>(x)

so `f(x,0,...,0,x)` (x zeros) ~= f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(x)

Any other tags?
Suggestions?
Does this interest you?

Comment: Having three winners doesn't really work. But having three separate questions is probably not the right solution either: they're close enough to be borderline dupes of each other. Perhaps the best way would be to score for the total length of the three functions, allowing the faster ones to call the slower ones but at the cost of having to name them. That might make for some interesting tradeoffs between using the functions directly vs having one function for `f_{w^2 a + wb}` which the others call with different values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor good suggestion, I changed the win condition. But I realized those a probably not the right functions since w² can be golfed really easily.

Comment: Why not do exact values?

Comment: Your solution for `f_{ω^2}` is very sub-optimal. See [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120228).

Answer (score 0):

## Just One More Time [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Challenge

Write a program or function that will run without error once, but will crash when run for the second time.

If you are writing a function, you may assume the function will be run twice within the same interpreter session or program.

If you are writing a program, you may assume the machine will not be rebooted between runs.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: I feel like the function version is much easier than the program version so I don't think you will see many programs in languages that could do both. Take C: `i=1;f(){return 1/i--;}`. I don't think you could reasonably ban "global" values to prevent this, but it's up to you if you even think this is a bad thing.

Comment: Will it run a third time?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The answer you gave is exactly the type I would be looking for

Comment: @Okx It would not be run a third time. For functions, the assumption is that the crash would kill the interpreter session/program. For programs, I just won't run it a third time.

Answer (score 0):

## What Tiles did I have?

Everyone should be aware of the scoring system in a classic board game: [Scrabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions). I remember going back into my old scrabble box and finding some old post-it notes containing old scores. I always wonder what the heck was played for some of the more insane point scores. That gave me the idea for this challenge...

---

English-language editions of Scrabble contain 100 letter tiles, in the following distribution:

- 0 points: * x 2 (These are the blank tiles)
- 1 point: E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
- 2 points: D ×4, G ×3
- 3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
- 4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
- 5 points: K ×1
- 8 points: J ×1, X ×1
- 10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1

---

Your challenge is, given a single integer input between `0 and 185`, output a corresponding sequence of scrabble tiles that sum to that score with a length between `2 and 100` characters in length.

## The Specifics

- The letters don't have to spell anything, they just have to sum to that score.
- You can only use a tile the number of times it exists (E.G. E can be used 12 times).
- The shortest word is 2 characters long, for an input of `0` you get `**`.
- Outputs will not match between answers, as there are many solutions.

## Inputs and Outputs

- Input should be a single integer, anything else is wrong.
- Output should be a single string, with no spaces, order of letters is arbitrary.

## Example (Potential Solution)

```
0   | **
1   | *E
2   | EE
[... Pattern Omitted ...]
12  | EEEEEEEEEEE
13  | EEEEEEEEEEEA
[... Pattern Omitted ...]
68  | EEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOONNNNNNRRRRRRRTTTTTTLLLLSSSSUUUU
[... Arbitrary Ordering Omitted ...]
185 | EEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOONNNNNNRRRRRRRTTTTTTLLLLSSSSUUUUDDDDGGGBBCCMMPPFFHHVVWWYYKJXZQ
```

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings): Whomever contacts Cthulhu using the dark arts first wins.

Comment: `Whomever contacts Cthulhu using the dark arts first wins.` that's bait

Comment: @StephenS wellp, if you want more bait check out 20 of my other random ass winning criterion for my sandboxies.

Comment: Sorry Sandbox sucks :/ can output be a list of one-char strings? and `integer` includes negatives, dunno if that's on purpose or not

Comment: @StephenS nono! That wasn't a diss on you or sandbox! That was just me stating that last 20 submission I've made to the sandbox I've put random winning criterion like "Winner buys dennis a subway footlong, or his countries' equivalent".

Comment: Also, it says an integer between 0 and 185. Also I mentioned words must be at least 2-chars. I feel like either my challenge's wording blows or you misread it a little. Probably more likely the challenge is worded poorly, I've had 2 already.

Comment: I made it a diss on Sandbox, that no one noticed them xD and I was looking in the #Input section for all the input specifics - I should have looked at the whole challenge, my bad. I just read `Input should be a single integer, anything else is wrong.` so that's what I assumed the whole rule for Input was (reading is hard)

Comment: @StephenS to be honest, reading isn't hard, it's contextual. I always have noticed in my career that I 100% understand anything that I create. Then, when explaining it to others, it may make literally 0 sense but be 100% viable in my head. Then like 10/12 people come forth saying "What the heck did you even try to write man?" And I realize, "what the hell did I even try to write?" Hahaha. The way I explain things to others can be horrifically inadequate by my own experience.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35741/194). It's a borderline dupe, in that the only real difference is a suitable wrapping loop.

Comment: A standard Scrabble board is 15 x 15, and even a "Super Scrabble" board is only 21 x 21.  Should the maximum word length be limited to 15 (instead of 100)?

Answer (score 0):

## Display the Undisplayable

I have sometimes seen answers to challenges, written in binary machine code. The users who post them usually display them in hexadecimal representation. This representation makes the code extremely long, and does not do them justice!

Thus, we should give them help, and I don't care if they don't need it. Your task will to write a program/function/eldritch incantation to *turn their beautifully golfed binary code into the shortest possible string of printable characters*.

### Input

A sequence of random binary data of random length. Use any of the standard IO methods (note to self: find the link to the Meta post).

### Output

A sequence of printable characters. Use any of the standard IO methods.

- If encoding is relevant, you are free to choose any encoding, provided you *clearly indicate which one you used in your answer*. What is relevant is the number of *characters* anyway.
- Whitespaces (regular space, new line, non-breaking space, form feed, etc.) are considered not printable. They can be added if you wish, but their presence or absence must not impact the decoding of the output.

### Conditions

- There must exist a program, that can take any possible output of your program, and turn it back into the input (providing it is not needed, but will be smiley'd at).
- If your program is run twice, with 2 inputs of same size, the 2 resulting outputs *must* have the same size.
- Standard loopholes apply.

### Score

The score is calcaulated as the number of bytes in the input, divided by the number of characters in the output. The higher the better.

If the score varies depending on the length of the input, take its average over input sizes from 1 to 1024 bytes included (I don't think we'll have answer 1 kb long here).

---

Giving an answer in a binary language (machine code, LLVM bitcode, etc.) *and* adding the output when run with its own binary source will be smiley'd at (but no bonus, unless it can also summon Cthulhu).

Don't forget to explain how your code works!

---

### Meta

- Do you think it's a good idea? Is there already a challenge like this one?
- Is there any blatant loophole/possible imporvements?
- What tag(s) do you recommend for this challenge? (please edit the answer)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sorry ^^

Comment: it's spelled `Cthulhu`

Comment: @Mayube That was what Mr.Xcoder's deleted comment was about... At first I didn't want to make a trivial edit, but since spelling of culture reference is such an important matter... Fixed! Now maybe I'll get more reactions about the challenge itself ^^

Comment: I think this needs a precise definition of *printable character*. Unicode doesn't define the term. But once that's provided this is just a base conversion with an awkward base and every answer should get the optimum score, so the scoring system doesn't work.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for using the sandbox! I hope things go well with your challenges :) That said, I have to agree with Peter Taylor, it seems like every answer will get the optimal score. I think requiring the optimal score and changing to code-golf will work better, but there are many other ways you could fix it. Good luck!

Comment: Worth noting that encoding is *always* gunna be relevant given non-printables don't count, as bytes `0x00-0x20` are non-printables by your definition, meaning if the given binary contains any of those bytes, ASCII can't be used.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I thought about something like that - maybe not the optimal score, but greater than a given value. And it seems I was right to use the sandbox, since there are already 2 potential loopholes detected!

Answer (score 0):

## Every Nth Line in Source Outputs N

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

Heavily inspired by [Hello, World! (Every other character)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128496/65836)

Related to my other Sandbox post [Every Nth Char in Source Outputs N](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13122/65836); **is it a dupe?**

Write a program that outputs `1`. When the first, third, fifth, etc. lines are removed, it outputs `2`. When all lines where their (`1`-based) index in the source, mod `N`, are not `0`, are removed, it should output `N`.

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). The winner is the program that works with the largest `N`, while working for all `n < N` (obviously, to run up to `N`, it has to be at least `N` lines long). If there is a tie, the winner is the shortest answer that reaches the largest `N`. Your program must at least work up to `N=2`, since I don't think any languages will struggle with simply printing `1`.

## Example

Examples are based off of this sample program:

```
test
hi
world
hello
12345
System.out.println(test);
timeout
let's dance
```

For the program to work for `N=1`, the original program should output `1`.

For the program to work for `N=2`, the following should output `2`:

```
hi
hello
System.out.println(test);
let's dance
```

For the program to work for `N=3`, the following should output `3`:

```
world
System.out.println(test);
```

For the program to work for `N=4`, the following should output `4`:

```
hello
let's dance
```

For the program to work for `N=5`, the following should output `5`:

```
12345
```

etc.

The highest `N` this program could work for is its line length, `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxing this mostly so *I* don't forget about it (as I don't want to initiate this so soon after v3). Unlikely to need any serious revision, but comments are appreciated none the less.

## Prisoner's Dilemma v4: The Amnesiac Gentlemen.

This is similar to [v3 Petri Dilemma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122118/prisoners-dilemma-v-3-petri-dilemma), except with one significant change: no one knows what round it is. The same setup, submission format, and scoring will be used.  For sandbox brevity, I'm only noting the differences from v3.

Bots will receive input at the beginning of its turn in the format:

`current points, enemies points, your previous moves, enemy's previous moves`

The format of the move list (both yours and the enemy's) will be a string of characters, "c" for cooperation "d" for defection, in order from first round to last. However this list will contain only the *first seven moves* of the game as well as *the most recent 7 moves* (as everyone knows, [you can only hold seven items in working memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two)). A String 14 characters or fewer would indicate a round at the beginning of the game where 14 total moves haven't yet been performed.  Later rounds would be indeterminate.

Additionally, as the current round number is not being passed in, bots will be unaware of when the end of the game comes (games will still be 200 rounds). This should prevent "Ah ha, last round, I backstab!" "Ah ha, but I backstab you first, *one round earlier!*" strategies, which is what dominated a large swath of the v3 strategic playspace (I did tests where all backstab-early bots were coded to all backstab on the same round and there were only two that performed sub-optimally as a result, both of which were set to backstab "before all n-Tit-for-Tat strategies", moving them back 1 rounds re-elevated them above n-Tit-for-Tat again, as well as which one backstabbed the other first determining the winner between them).  While several bots from v3 would be valid submissions in v4, all of the *winning bots* utilize more data than v4 will let them have, opening up the playing field for new techniques.

Here are four sample strategies that will be entered to start with:

### Tit for Tat

```
def titfortatfunc(mypoints, enpoints, mylist, enlist):
    if not enlist or enlist[counter-1] == "c":
        return "c"
    else:
        return "d"
```

### RandomPick

```
from random import choice
def randompickfunc(mypoints, enpoints, mylist, enlist):
    return choice(["d", "c"])
```

### Cooperator

```
def cooperatorfunc(mypoints, enpoints, mylist, enlist):
    return "c"
```

### Defector

```
def defectorfunc(mypoints, enpoints, mylist, enlist):
    return "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

## (Code Golf) How Many Notes Are There?

### Background

Most music games (MUG) describes the "instructions" that the player must follow as "notes". When the charts (set of notes) are first available, MUG players usually record the chart as a video and upload them to video sites. However, unless playing a full combo (able to pick up all notes) that the combo count directly shows the number of notes, it is usually not practical to count the number of notes one by one directly (since there are usually hundreds of notes), so they calculate that from the scores that may show on those videos if the score formula is known.

One of those examples is **jubeat**, which is somehow like a MUG version of "Whack-a-Mole". Although officially "instructions" are called "chips", players have the consensus to call them "notes". (For those who don't know what jubeat is please check it out here: [jubeat - RemyWiki](https://remywiki.com/Jubeat_Information))

### Objective

What you have to do, is to:

- Write **a program or function**,
- Which accepts a list of integers as the only input,
- That **calculates the numbers of notes which is possible for all** the given "basic scores".

### Requirements

- The input can be **an array of integers or a string containing those integers** (Please indicate the input format).
- The integers in the input are **guaranteed to be in the range of [0, 900000] inclusive**.
- A case (`NOTES` in the formula) is possible means that, for each integer in the input, **there exists** a variable `ACH`, **when substituted** into the formula below, the formula **evaluates to that integer**. (See The Formula and Test Cases for details)
- All possible cases **within the range [1, 1100] inclusive must be included** in the output.
- The output **can be an array of integers or a string containing the results** (Please indicate the output format).
- If there is no case fulfilling the requirements, the program or function should either **return an empty array, an empty string, null, or any objects indicating absence of results**.
- **NO RUNTIME EXCEPTIONS shall be thrown** in any circumstances.

### The Formula

The max score is 1000000, but here we only consider `BASIC_SCORE`, whose maximum is 900000.

The `BASIC_SCORE` is calculated by `BASIC_SCORE = floor(floor(ACH * 100000 / NOTES) * 0.9)`, where `ACH` is an integer in the range `[0, NOTES*10]` inclusive except `NOTES*10-1` and `NOTES*10-2`.

As a concrete example, take `ACH=6850, NOTES=900`, we have `BASIC_SCORE = floor(floor(6850 * 100000 / 900) * 0.9) = 684999`.

As a result, `NOTES=900` is a possible case for the basic score 684999.

### Test cases

```
 Input                                    | Output
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 896757, 846353, 844486                   | 916
 891000, 893999                           | (all multiples of 30 within [1, 1100])
 899736                                   | 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027
                                          | (342, 683, 684 are false positives because  
                                          |  in these cases ACH = NOTES*10-1 or 
                                          |  ACH = NOTES*10-2)
 873540, 802468                           | (none: no case fits all inputs.
                                          |  some cases do fit some inputs but not all)
 0, 900000                                | (all values within [1..1100])
 800000                                   | (none)
```

### Rules and Winning Criteria

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the source code with the shortest length (in terms of bytes) wins. Standard loopholes apply.

Answer (score 0):

## Poor Man's Ransomware

This challenge is loosely inspired by the cheapo-enigma machine question. However, I beleive that the differences are substantial enough that this would not be a dupe. Feedback welcome.

---

You have been captured by a morally questionable "employer" and forced to write a piece of "ransomware". All it has to do is take in a string "in whatever format" and output another string (which can be used to recover the files) Essentially, across the set of all possible inputs (infinite) you will define a one to one function.

Participants will then publish their code to stack-exchange, where other aspiring "hackers" will try to break your code. A "cop" submission will consist of a byte count a sample plaintext and a sample "encrypted" file as well as an encrypted copy of your code.

Robbers will work tirelessly in another thread to reproduce your code. Any submission which correctly produces the corresponding "encrypted" files when fed the sample plaintext and itself will be considered to be cracked.

If your code lasts 7 days or longer you may mark your submission as "safe" by publishing the source code for the encryptor and a decryptor. Until this time robbers may still work to break your code. If anyone finds that a specific decryptor fails on a certain plaintext it is invalid.

The winning cop has the shortest safe submission and the winning robber has the largest sum of the bytes of his cracked cops. Ties go to the earlier poster. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm not sure how much of the history of cops-and-robbers you are aware of. In the early days it was almost killed off as an interesting challenge type precisely by crypto, because it's so easy to make a problem which depends on e.g. [factoring a large prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36790/194). In some senses this would be a duplicate of the very first cops-and-robbers.

Comment: Almost every cnr problem can be  solved using cryptography. Would you then say that almost every cops and robbers problem is dupe of the other ones?

Comment: Many cnr's now try to ban the use of cryptography precisely to avoid this problem.

Comment: @PeterTaylor could I ban Crypto built ins?

Comment: What would be the point? It's crypto that's the problem, not crypto built-ins.

Comment: Maybe it might not be that bad of a thing?

Comment: I tmight be worth asking about this somewhere

Comment: It would be easy to implement some simple crypto and hardcode a key, making it impossible for robbers.

Comment: Isn't that what most cnr challenges center on?

Answer (score 0):

## Count bytes like a Java golfer

Java is verbose, everybody knows that. Sometimes, here on PPCG, it happens that a Java answer is shorter than 60 characters, but most of the time it's longer, way longer! And the Java golfers here often post improvement suggestions in comments.

Alas, the PPCG website is based on the stack software, which [invisibly cuts `<code>` comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert) according to an obscure rule, which I shall name the "Java golfer's bane", making it impossible to get an accurate byte-count by copy-pasting.

The rule in question is the following:

- in a `<code>` tag, insert two invisible characters

  - the first time after 60 non-whitespace consecutive characters
  - then subsequently ever 20 non-whitespace consecutive characters

### Challenge

Your goal is to help us, poor Java golfers, to **get the byte-count straight** from when we copy/paste code from comments.

SE software rules are, I'm sure, complex, so we will simplify a bit, but not that much.

- Your input:

  - is mappable to UTF-8;
  - must support codepoints until at least `U+FFFF`;
  - will contain only characters with codepoints greater than or equal to `U+0020`;
  - must be a string or a characters array/list if those accept unicode characters, or else must be an integer (16 bits minimum) array/list. Unless I forgot anything obvious, no other input format is allowed.
- If a sequence of non-whitespace characters in the input contains more than 60 characters:

  - keep the 60 first characters, then skip the next 2 characters;
  - then until you meet a whitespace, keep the next 20 characters and skip the next 2.
  - We don't care which are the two stripped characters.
- Your output is the size of the string after being sanitized, in bytes as encoded in UTF-8! You must support very long Java answers, up to 500 characters (not bytes).

  - You don't *need* to map to UTF-8 since I give the rule on how to count without mapping, but in some languages it might be easier to actually map!
- The [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/16236) are naturally forbidden.
- This is codegolf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

#### You may assume the following:

- the only whitespace character you will ever get is the space (`U+0020`). I abuse the term whitespace by including the start of the string as well in its meaning.
- no whitespace will be at positions 62, 94, 116, (+22) ... after the previous whitespace

#### You may not assume the following:

- The skippable characters will exclusively be the ones SE actually uses (`U+200C` `U+200B`);
- you will get only ASCII characters;
- you will not get any [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

#### Bonus

- if your code supports Unicode code points up to `U+1FFFFF`, you can remove 10% off your byte count, do not round the resut.

### How to count the number of UTF-8 bytes?

If you haven't a builtin for that, [Wikipedia gives us the rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), based on code points:

```
first code point  |  last code point  |  # bytes
U+0000            |  U+007F           |  1
U+0080            |  U+07FF           |  2
U+0800            |  U+FFFF           |  3
U+10000           |  U+1FFFFF         |  4
```

Wikipedia goes beyond those number, but the [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) capped this mapping to 4 bytes, so we thank it!

### Test cases

Work in progress!

---

Notes for review:

- Suggested tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)
- Related:

  - [Bytes/Character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83673/16236) (different as there is an additional string manipulation)

Answer (score 0):

What feedback do you have for me?

## Challenge

Convert and print out a time in a 12-hour format. `HH:MM AM/PM`

#### Examples

Input:

- `'Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Sat Jun 31 2018 08:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`

Ouput:

- `09:14 PM`
- `08:06 AM`
- `01:14 AM`
- `09:06 AM`

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution in bytes wins
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You may use functions as well as programs

Comment: I think this question has been covered pretty thoroughly by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57552/whats-the-time-chap/57557) and [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/output-the-current-time), and would probably be closed as a dupe.

Comment: did not realize it had already been done :(

Comment: It's not _exactly_ the same question, but I think that area has been pretty much covered. Now, what you could do is use [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105858/12-hour-to-24-hour-time-converter) as a model, but go from 24-hour time to 12-hour time :)

Comment: I like that Idea! in fact I could take it a step further and convert a string in the following format: `2017-07-01T02:58:38.799Z` to 12 hour time

Comment: [@musicman523](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69054/musicman523) I made an edit to the question, what do you think?

Comment: I definitely like this better. You should add more test cases with different days (for example, does `1` come out as `1` or `01`?), months, days of the week, etc. so there is no confusion about the input format

Comment: ok, sounds good. Is that enough test cases? feel free to edit and add more details.

Comment: I feel like the testcases should be formatted like `input -> output\ninput -> output`. What about the midday and midnight?

Comment: Ok, Sounds good. I am posting it.

Answer (score 0):

## Help! My code has exploded! [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

*Insert backstory here*

### Task:

Your task is to create a program, which must follow these rules:

- It must be able to be split exactly into pieces of the same length in bytes.
- Once you have separated your program into pieces, your program must print `1` if the first "piece" is removed from your code, `2` if the second "piece" is removed, etc., until the program prints `n` if the `n`th piece is removed.

For example, if your program was the following:

```
aabbccdd
```

And it could be split into `4` equal parts of length `2`, then these programs must result in the following outputs:

```
bbccdd -> 1 (aa is removed)
aaccdd -> 2 (bb is removed)
aabbdd -> 3 (cc is removed)
aabbcc -> 4 (dd is removed)
```

### Scoring requirements:

Your program is scored based on the number of parts that it can be split into, with each part following the rules defined above. The more parts, the higher the score.

In the event of a tie, there is a "hierarchy" of scoring methods (with the next method in the list being used when there is a tie):

- Number of parts the program can be split equally into
- Size of the full program, in bytes (shortest byte-count wins)
- Time posted (first poster wins)

### Rules:

- Each byte in the program must belong to one part.
- Each part in the program must be of equal length.

Comment: You can make arbitrarily long programs that do this. I suggest instead that each answer should describe a pattern that can go to infinity (with possibly a starting piece). However scoring is difficult, since I forsee that some answers will have the segment number within each segment, meaning that going from 99 segments to 100 segments may require more characters per segment.

Comment: Proof of concept for arbitrary number of segments: https://gist.github.com/shelvacu/e04c237ad8d1c066a7fd8b5170261e25 However, that was still fun to make so I definitely think there's potential here.

Comment: @Shelvacu That seems like a really cool idea, yeah. Will change my question.

Comment: @Shelvacu Hmmm, I'm not sure how to properly make this into a challenge, TBH. I might scrap it. **EDIT:** I might have an idea, but I need to completely rewrite it. I might just delete this whole thing.

Comment: If you don't want to post it I will. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

## What's Underneath the Sine Wave?

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Task

Your task is to output a part of the sine wave out of any characterss of your choosing and on any background of your choosing. The wave can start and end either on the highest or the lowest point of the wave if both are the same.

The challenges main part is what happens below the wave (or above if you chose to start at the peaks of the wave). For each column, looking top-to-down it should repeat until the bottom the segment of spaces until the wave.

#### Or a visual explanation:

Start with a sine wave of your choosing (this is not a valid one as it isn't 50x20, but smaller to save space):

```
             ####             
           ##    ##           
          #        #          
         #          #         
        #            #        
       #              #       
      #                #      
     #                  #     
    #                    #    
  ##                      ##  
##                          ##
```

and then, look top-down and until the 1st encounter of a non-background character record the characters and then repeat them:

```
        ↓   ↓####             
        ↓  ##  P ##           
      4x↓ # ↓  P   #          
        ↓#  P  P    #         
        X   ↓  P     #        
       #↓   P  P      #       
      # ↓4x ↓  P       #      
     #  ↓   P  P        #     
    #   ↓   ↓  P         #    
  ##    P   P  P          ##  
##      ↓   ↓  P            ##
```

so for this the output would be

```
             ####             
           ########           
          #  ####  #          
         # ######## #         
        #    ####    #        
       #  ##########  #       
      #      ####      #      
     #   # ######## #   #     
    #     #  ####  #     #    
  ##    #  ########  #    ##  
##           ####           ##
```

### Clarifications

- There can be any amount of leading/trailing lines with any amount of whitespace
- On each line there can be extra leading whitespace, as long as the amount is equal on all lines
- The width should be at least 50 characters total (excluding columns of only whitespace)
- The height should be at least 20 characters total (excluding lines of whitespace only)
- The repeating bottom parts *must* be cut from the bottom (or top) of the wave
- Inaccuracies due to rounding or floating-point errors can be dismissed
- The background character has to be constant
- The wave characters can be different, as long as they aren't ever equal to the background
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code per language wins!

### Sample outputs

```
                         XXXXXX
                       XXXXXXXXXX
                     XX  XXXXXX  XX
                    X  XXXXXXXXXX  X
                   X     XXXXXX     X
                  X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X
                XX       XXXXXX       XX
               X    X  XXXXXXXXXX  X    X
              X      XX  XXXXXX  XX      X
             X     X   XXXXXXXXXX   X     X
            X            XXXXXX            X
           X      X XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X      X
          X              XXXXXX              X
         X      XX     XXXXXXXXXX     XX      X
        X          X XX  XXXXXX  XX X          X
       X       X    X  XXXXXXXXXX  X    X       X
      X                  XXXXXX                  X
    XX        X   X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X   X        XX
   X                     XXXXXX                     X
XXX          X     XX  XXXXXXXXXX  XX     X          XXX

..................................................
DCB....................QPONM....................10
...A9........0.......SRQPONMLK.......C........32
.....8..........X...T..QPONM..J...F..........4
......7.......Z...VU.SRQPONMLK.IH...D.......5
.......6...............QPONM...............6
........5......Y.W..TSRQPONMLKJ..G.E......7
.........4.............QPONM.............8
...................U.SRQPONMLK.I
..........3.......V.T..QPONM..J.H.......9
...........2....X....SRQPONMLK....F....A
............1..........QPONM..........B
.................W.UTSRQPONMLKJI.G
.............0.........QPONM.........C
..............Z...V..SRQPONMLK..H...D
...............Y....T..QPONM..J....E
...................U.SRQPONMLK.I
................X......QPONM......F
.................W..TSRQPONMLKJ..G
..................V....QPONM....H
...................U.SRQPONMLK.I
....................T..QPONM..J
.....................SRQPONMLK
.......................QPONM..................................
...
.
....
```

## sandbox

- please suggest (or just edit in) ways of making this clearer
- Anything missing?
- Should I make this challenge take input, rather than being an broad kolmogorov-complexity challenge?

Comment: Is the sample output for input `X`?

Comment: @officialaimm The characters can be of your choosing, there's no input currently

Comment: So, all the positions marked by `X` should have same character or can have different characters?

Comment: @officialaimm They can have any characters

Comment: I think its better if you showcase sample output with different characters then.

Comment: I can't tell what the task is from reading the description, or from looking at the example. It might help to walk through a few example columns to make it clear, then follow up with the full wave examples after that.

Comment: @trichoplax good idea

Comment: Thanks. A second look at the examples was enough for me to grasp the pattern, but a step by step example would probably have got it across quicker.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Ten years ago, a secret encryption key used by DVD players was published online. When the industry tried to censor it, [the internet reacted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy) by republishing it widely—creatively incorporating the key onto shirts, a flag and even in song.

If this code golf community had existed, I'm sure we would have joined in.

## Challenge

Output the number 13256278887989457651018865901401704640.

## Example input and output

Input:

Not applicable.

Output:

> 13256278887989457651018865901401704640

Comment: This is code-golf I suppose, you should mention the winning condition.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that there's any way to compress this other than base conversion?

Answer (score 0):

## Decode Reddit's Voting System [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## Background

Users with a high enough reputation on Stack Exchange can see the number of upvotes and downvotes on each question and answer. On Reddit, however, the net vote count and percentage of upvotes are displayed. Unfortunately due to rounding errors, it is impossible to determine exactly how many upvotes and downvotes occurred.

## Challenge

Given a nonzero net vote count and a percentage of upvotes, return all possible pairs of the numbers of upvotes and downvotes.

## Constraints

The net vote count can be any integer in the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`.

The percentage can be a whole number in the range `[0, 100]`, or a floating point number in the range `[0, 1]` with no more than two digits; you may decide which format to accept.

The percentage represents the percentage of votes which are upvotes, *rounded to the nearest integer*. So a value of `93%` could be anywhere in the range `[92.5%, 93.5%)` that would result

The maximum numbers of upvotes and downvotes will not fall outside the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`; that is, you should be safe using 32-bit signed integers.

You may not return two ranges representing all possible amounts of downvotes and upvotes; you *must* specify which numbers of upvotes correspond to which numbers of downvotes; hence you must return all possible pairs.

## Test Cases

```
1, 67%  -> [(2, 1)]
1, 100% -> [(1, 0)]
1, 60%  -> [(3, 2)]
0, 50%  -> [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), ...]; cases like this will not be valid input
More involved ones to come...
```

## Meta

Anything I can do to make this more clear or more fun?

Comment: 1. Does "net vote count" mean upvotes minus downvotes? 2. The listed input `0, 100%` is a special case (`(0-0)/(0+0) = NaN%` or a division by zero exception) so it should be mentioned explicitly in the spec, not just added as a test case. 3. Input `0, 50%` would have 2^31 valid outputs, so that should also get an explicit mention because of the potential for answers to fail due to array size limits etc. Combined with point 2, I would suggest editing the question to guarantee that the net vote count will never be 0.

Comment: "Unfortunately due to rounding errors, it is impossible to determine exactly how many upvotes and downvotes occurred." I was under the impression that reddit adds some random noise to the net votes (not sure about the percentage) to throw off bots or something.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you, updated

Comment: @MartinEnder I _believe_ they simply stop reporting exact values after it reaches a certain threshold, but I'm not sure. For this challenge we'll assume they don't add any noise

Answer (score 0):

## Create The Correct Path

*Which would be better code golf with shortest code and being able to run on at least two operating systems or code challenge and scoring by how many operating systems it can run on?*

([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) OR [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)) [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system)

Given an input create a program that when ran on different operating systems creates a path for each one. For example, when ran on Windows:

```
[ "folder1", "folder2" ] -> folder1\folder2
```

**Input**

An array of strings or any suitable alternative. The input can be empty, in which case you would just return an empty string.

**Output**

The correct path for the operating system the program has been ran on.

Comment: I'm mainly looking at feedback for what people think of this challenge before developing it further.

Comment: I think you should include other operating systems with different paths separators in the challenge itself.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I was going to, was waiting to see if I should go with [tag:code-golf] or [tag:code-challenge] before writing up the formatting for all the examples.

Answer (score 0):

### Abbreviate a rename

After you commit a rename, `git` reminds you but tries to avoid showing the full source and target path. It does this by splitting the path into components, extracting identical leading and trailing components, then using them to abbreviate the rename. (Other output that `git` produces is not relevant here.) Here is an example:

```
foo/bar/baz/quux.c => foo/baz/bar/quux.c
```

The leading component `foo` and trailing component `quux.c` is the same, so this becomes

```
foo/{bar/baz => baz/bar}/quux.c
```

This also works when one of the components is empty, e.g.:

```
foo/{bar/baz => }/quux.c
foo/{ => baz/bar}/quux.c
```

Please write a program or function that abbreviates a rename. The input can be a pair of strings or a single string with a delimiter which can be `=>` or newline or something else not typically found in a file name. The output should be a single string containing a `=>` as shown. You can assume that neither string is a prefix of the other (`git` doesn't abbreviate the rename in that case for some reason.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins!

Answer (score 0):

If you've come here, you probably know what [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is, and that's what I'm going to assume.

### Story

(I guess)

Keyboards are input devices we use all the time. They existed before mice and touch screen, etc.

Their fundamentals have not changed: when you press a key down, a signal is sent to the computer. When you release it, another signal is sent.

So here's the **challenge**: calculate the minimum number of signals(length of a signal does not matter) depending on the input string.

### Example:

Input:

```
test
```

Output:

```
8
```

> Explanation:
>   All keys have to be pressed down and released

Input2:

```
TEst
```

Output2:

```
10
```

> Explanation:
>   Shift has to be pressed, then T, down, up, E, down, up, then release shift, then s down, up, then t down, up, totalling up to 10.

### Rules

Any language is accepted.
This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.
Programs with incorrect outputs will be disqualified.

### Happy golfing!

## Edit:

The keyboard layout used should be this: http://dry.sailingissues.com/keyboard-US-International.png

Only characters in this keyboard layout will be used (+lowercase letters).

Using Caps-Lock is ok, since it DOES have an advantage: numbers remain numbers while letters become uppercase.

Thanks for the feedback so far.

Comment: I think this might be a dupe, lemme see if I can find the original. EDIT: Ah, it's your challenege. I suggest deleting it from main while you work on it here; you can edit and then undelete it when it's ready.

Comment: Test cases? Your comment about caps lock is a good example of an edge case which should be explicitly covered by the test cases, and implies another where a shift covers a substring which mixes upper-case letters and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

## Let's simplify polynomials

In many situations we have to expand mathematical expressions containing variables, for example, calculating characteristic polynomials, expanding products of polynomials, etc. It is trivial if the variables are known (in this case, we just substitute the variables with the corresponding values and evaluate the expression by a calculator), but not so simple if we need to manually expand the expression.

## Motivation

Consider the cases with only one variable (say, x). Suppose the coefficients are *sufficiently small*. Then, a simple way is to take x to be some number (e.g. 1000), evaluate the expression and convert the numerical answer back to a polynomial.

Here is an example. Suppose we need to expand

[image]

Put [image] and evaluate it using a dumb calculator. The answer is [image].

By running the program/function with input `-984982000`, one should get

```
[-1, 15, 18, 0] (descending order)
```

, and so the expanded polynomial is [image].

## The task

Write a program or function which satisfies the following:

- The input is an integer, which is calculated by substituting x = 1000 in a polynomial (which you have to find out).
- Output the coefficients, guaranteed to be in the range [-499,499] (inclusive), and to be integers. You can represent the polynomial in either ascending or descending order, so long as it is consistent across different runs. You can return a list of integers, print to standard output (with non-numeric separators), etc.

## Examples

```
Input         Output (descending power)
1003005007    1 3 5 7
1001          1 1
999           1 -1
998994        1 -1 -6
-998994       -1 1 6
1000001       1 0 1
0             0


Input
1003005007

Valid outputs                     Invalid outputs
[1 3 5 7] (descending order)      1357 (coefficients are not separated)
[7 5 3 1] (ascending order)       7531 (coefficients are not separated)
"1 3 5 7" (descending order)      "1357" (coefficients are not separated)
"7, 5, 3, 1" (ascending order)    [1 5 3 7] (neither ascending nor descending order)
7                                 "10305070" (numeric separator "0")
5
3
1 (ascending order)
```

## Rules

1. Standard loophole applies.
2. Your program/function should be able to at least handle polynomials of degree 3. Also, the input might be negative. Therefore, using a suitable data type is necessary.
3. You can take the input in integer or string format. It is guaranteed that the input is a valid integer.
4. The shortest program/function (in bytes) wins. Good luck!

Comment: I think this input-output pair violates the order-criterion: `1000001       1 0 1`

Comment: What do you mean with *"consistent across different runs"*? Why don't you restrict this challenge to just have ascending coefficients? (Also please include wheter e.g. `1 3 5 7` means `x^3 + 3x^2+5x+7` or `1+3x+5x^2+7x^3`.

Comment: @flawr To avoid confusion, a program or function should not output in different orders when different inputs are given (e.g. 1003005007 -> [1 3 5 7] and 999 -> [-1 1]). So `1 3 5 7` can mean both, but it has to be specified. To solve the problem one way is to find out and remove the leading/trailing coefficient recursively, and it probably costs extra bytes to reverse the list of coefficients.

Comment: Ah so the order has nothing to do with the challenge but just with the input/output? (I first thought we have to find polynomiasl where the *coefficients* are in are in ascending order.) Perhpas clarify that this is not about the coefficients but about the representation of the polynomials. And as I said before please specify that in your examples the constant monomial comes first, and the coefficients of the larger powers come after.

Comment: I don't understand what the question has to do with the title.

Comment: @PeterTaylor see my edit

Answer (score 0):

## Rock Paper Scissors, but it's a big, custom tournament

We all know "Rock, Paper, Scissors", and it's pretty variated.

A world tournament is held every year, and it's dang popular.

However, the contestants are able to bring their own ways of play to the plate, and they play with them.

## The challenge:

Create a program that, by process of elimination through RPS, determines the winner of the tournament.

## The tournament rules:

- No slackers. (Let the amount of players be an integer equally divisible by 2. [In other words, an even number.])
- You can bring 2 of either of the 4 variants:

  ***None:*** Play regular RPS.

  ***RPSLV:***  Play "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock" (play diagram shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rock_paper_scissors_lizard_spock.png)).

  ***Best out of three:*** Play 3 rounds; if by round 2, a player wins the round and has two points, they auto win. Else, winner of the next round wins.

  ***Double RPS:*** Play with four hands (two hands used by each player).
- You cannot bring two of the same variant.
- In order to use a variant, the two players must have the same type of variant. If there are no matching variants, the gameplay is automatically ***None***.
- However, if there are more than one variant matches, a game of mode ***None*** will be played. The winner of the game mentioned decides what mode they play for the match they will play to see who goes to the next round.
- In the case of a tie, replay until a win occurs (for all modes)
- There can be only one winner.

## The coding rules:

- All choices must be randomized (no strategies, to make this simple.).
- No standard loopholes.
- Give an explanation as much as you can. (If possible, include a "Try it out online" sample.)

## Sample Input/Output:

You must make a table variable with all the player numbers, from 1 to n, with two variants for each player.

n = the amount of players you intend to enter.

**Example Input:**

```
Player # | Var 1 | Var 2
1        | RSPLV | None
2        | None  | x2 RPS
3        | x2 RPS| Boo3
4        | Boo3  | x2 RPS
...      |...    | ...
```

Make a `func()` that:

1: Checks the variants of the next two availible players on the list, starting at player 1, then does the second to third last rules depending on what happens.

2: Makes the pair engage in battle, gameplay depending on the chosen variant.

3: Finally, boot the loser off the game and add the winner to the next list (round). (The "boot the loser" part isn't that required, but I recommend so as to not make the program add a player to the next table.)

**Output (uses table from input):**

```
 Round 1:
 1 vs. 2 // None, since the None variant matches both of them
 ["Rock"/*1*/,"Scissors"/*2*/]
 1 wins

 3 vs. 4 // They have more than one match, so they fight for who decides
 ["P"/*3*/,"S"/*4*/]
 4 wins, and chooses Best out of 3 
 Match 1:
 ["P"/*3*/,"R"/*4*/] // 1(3) - 0(4)

 Match 2:
 ["P"/*3*/,"S"/*4*/] // 1(3) - 1(4)

 Match 3:
 ["P"/*3*/,"R"/*4*/] // 2(3) - 1(4)
 3 wins

 Round 2:
 1 vs. 4 //No matches, defaults to None
 ["R"/*1*/,"R"/*4*/] // No-one wins
 ["R"/*1*/,"S"/*4*/]
 1 wins the tournament
```

## Misc. requirements (some optional):

A {!} means it is required.

- {!} Print each match, and who wins.
- {!} Print the tournament winner.
- {!} The number of players must be flexible.
- Print the table for each round.

## Scenarios:

**None:**

```
a vs. b //Either they have no matches, or they have both None matches
["R"/*a*/,"S"/*b*/]
a wins
```

**RPSLV (will make this one quick):**

```
a vs. b //RPSLV chosen
["V"/*a*/,"L"/*b*/]
b wins
```

**Best out of Three:**

***Scenario 1: (a tie occurs at match 2)***

```
a vs. b //Boo3 chosen
Match 1:
["P"/*a*/,"S"/*b*/] // 0(a) - 1(b)

Match 2:
["P"/*a*/,"P"/*b*/] // tie
["P"/*a*/,"S"/*b*/] // 1(a) - 1(b)

Match 3:
["R"/*a*/,"S"/*4*/] // 2(a) - 1(b)
a wins
```

***Scenario 2: (a player has two points by the end of match 2)***

```
a vs. b //Boo3 chosen
Match 1:
["P"/*a*/,"S"/*b*/] // 0(a) - 1(b)

Match 2:
["S"/*a*/,"P"/*b*/] // 0(a) - 2(b)
b automatically wins
```

**Double RPS:**

```
a vs. b //x2 RPS chosen
[("R", "P")/*a*/, ("S", "S")/*b*/] // lock
[("P", "P")/*a*/, ("S", "S")/*b*/]
b wins
```

## Both the coding and tournament rules apply to your code.

## For sandbox use only (won't be included in real question)

I don't know if this kind of problem is suitable for code golf, it could be a programming puzzle, I'm not sure. Go ahead in the comments and tell me what mode it should be, and if I should improve it. (Also, sorry for the mix of Python
lists and C++ comments, if it confuses you.) A ** means the choice is random.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG, and thanks for using the sandbox! I had a hard time following what you intended from this challenge. The rules are rather disorganised with many points early on not making sense until later. For example, you say: "No slackers. (Let p be a number equally divisible by 2.)" before it is clear that you intend for us to implement a single elimination tournament. I had no idea what "p" was supposed to mean, or why this should matter. I'd recommend trying to explain this to someone verbally, perhaps, to try to organise your thoughts better. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, thanks. I will edit the problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what we're supposed to implement. The controller for the tournament and what else? Do we also implement the players, so that we're simulating the entire thing? Or do we have to provide some kind of API for the players? In the first case, how does "*The winner decides what mode they play*" work?

Comment: Again, any multi-choice is random.

Answer (score 0):

#### Challenge

Take a number and output it with 4 digits or less using letters and numbers. For example; `270,030` would turn into `2.7K`.

#### Key

Billion -> `B`

Million -> `M`

Thousand -> `K`

#### Rules

- You may choose to accept input numbers that include commas delimiting every three decimal places (such as `123,456,789`).
- Round to nearest, half-up.
- Numbers will only go up to a trillion.
- The mantissa part of the answer should be at least 1.
- All letters must be uppercase and as specified below.
- Outputs must be 4 or less characters wide.
- Outputs must be as mathematically precise as possible. Example:

  - `154,893` -> `100K` **NOT OK**
  - `154,893` -> `155K` **GOOD**
- If there are multiple outputs with the same mathematical precision, return the shortest one. (If they are the same length, you may return either.) Example:

  - `1000` -> `1000` **NOT OK**
  - `1000` -> `1K` **GOOD**

#### Examples:

```
1,234,567 -> 1.2M
102 -> 102
1000 -> 1K
1001 -> 1001
100,000 -> .1M
12,345,678,912 -> 12B
1,452,815,612 -> 1.5B
```

#### Submissions

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in each language wins
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: I made a bunch of edits, feel free to roll back any changes you dislike. For the case of `100,000`, should you return `.1M`, `0.1M`, or `100K`?

Comment: I like `100K` best, maybe we should change it to 5 or less characters. Also thanks for the edits.

Comment: Personally I think 4 characters is fine. To further elaborate on my question: If you are outputting a decimal, do you require a leading 0 or would you allow `.1M`?

Comment: I think `.1M` should be `100K` and we should allow up to 4 digits (or under 5).

Comment: Oh, I thought it was 4 digits or less. My misunderstanding. If `.1M` is not allowed then you should clarify in the question that the "number" part of the answer should be at least 1. However this seems rather arbitrary to me, when your original goal was to get the number as short as possible

Comment: Ok, I will specify. thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. The "*"number"*" part is called the *mantissa*. 2. I think "*as specified below*" should be "*as specified above*". 3. `154,894` -> `1.5K` is not **GOOD**. It should be `155K`. 4. Or should it? I don't see any rules specifying [how to round](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5608/194). 5. `1K` has less precision than `1000` because it gives fewer significant figures.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have applied your edits, anything else?

Comment: I am going to post this unless anyone has any other feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## Fighting a Land War

In this KoTH, you need to earn as much money as you can while fighting over tiles to take over.

The board is a large hexagon made up of 91 smaller hexagonal tiles (A 6x6 hexagon)

Each tile is either:

1. An impassable mountain
2. Hills that generate production.  They start out with a random value (between 2 to 4)
3. Valleys that generate money. Their starting value is the distance from the nearest corner multiplied by 2
   (between 2 and 10)

[image: Board]

There are 6 players in each game, each starting in a different corner of the hexagon.  The corner will always be a hill(4).  Turn order is randomized at the start of the game.

Each turn, the following happens:

1. Each tile that you have owned for N^2 turns (where N is an integer) increases in value by 1
2. You earn money/production.  (Equal to the sum of the valley/hill values)
3. You can spend production on defenses or capturing tiles.

   - Adding `N TileDefense` costs `N Production`
   - Capturing a tile with `N TileDefense` costs `1 + 2*N Production`
   - You can only capture a tile if it is a non-mountain tile that is adjacent to your current tiles.

Notes:

- Tiles lose all defense on capture.
- Multiple players can upgrade a single tile

  - The turn counter for tile upgrades is player-specific.  This means that if you capture a tile from another player, the turn counter starts at 0.
  - If you capture a tile you've owned before, it starts off where you left it.

And that's it.  The player with the most money after 500? turns wins.

Comment: 1. "*Each tile is either*" determined how? Randomly or in a fixed pattern? 2. How does step 3 work? As many rounds of capture and defence as you like? Or do you declare all of your attacks and defences at the start of the round? This has implications both for defending a tile on the turn you capture it and for blitzkrieg captures.

Comment: 1. I'm still thinking about this.  I think I'm going to randomly generate a triangular segment, and then mirror it across to the other 5 segments.  2. Oooh...I haven't thought about this.  Thanks, I'll give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

## Write a code poem [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

It is said that Larry Wall, creator of Perl, wrote a poem titled "Black Perl" in said language, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Perl).

The poem is fully functional (working syntax, no runtime errors, etc. [no errors in general]).

## The challenge:

In any language (practical languages recommended), write a haiku (example of one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku).

## Coding rules:

- The poem must be able to function properly (no errors).
- Unlike Wall's poem, you must run through the whole program (exits only at the end).
- If you define a function to act as a word, it will count towards your poem.
- Caught errors and other error-handling tricks are valid.

## Misc rules:

- You cannot use multi-line strings or line continue symbols, etc. (No multi-line functions/tricks).
- Brackets, parentheses, and other grouping symbols (with the exception of < and > as operators are ignored unless as a string.

## Example lines (written in Python, not the best, probably):

```
while i_love ....: # i_love counts as two words

i_am > than_you # read symbols/operators as words

"""my love for ...
is ....... by ...""" # Invalid, as stated by one of the misc. rules

me(,"john", "abby",
    "and liz") # invalid, line continuation
```

## Winning:

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so submission with the highest amount of votes wins.

## For sandbox only:

How can I improve on this challenge? Is there anything else I should add? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: This is currently both too broad and unclear. What does "work" mean? What is a "script"? What is allowed besides "words" (whatever those are)? How do we measure answers against each other? Try to look at some of the challenges on this site to get a better feel for what we do here - I'm afraid this is very far off the mark. You can try asking other users in chat, once you get some reputation, about ways to make this fit better, but personally I don't think this kind of challenge is a good fit for this site.

Comment: I like the idea, but I think you need to be more specific in what is valid and invalid. If my script is just one giant multi-line string, it satisfies your requirement, but obviously that's not what you're going for.

Comment: Will edit the question.

Comment: Are caught errors allowed?

Comment: You mean stuff like `try`?

Comment: Who wins? What's the criterion for deciding that?

Comment: @Riker I am currently thinking about that.

Comment: @S.G.Harmonia yeah

Comment: I do think this question might be too broad. Maybe make it so it has to be a haiku? And then score by [popularity contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: 1. I have no idea where to close the parenthesis in "*Brackets, parentheses, and other grouping symbols (with the exception of < and > as operators are ignored unless as a string.*". 2. A popularity contest should have a clear spec to identify valid answers, and an indication of what aspect of the answers makes them good. It's a hack to judge subjective contests like https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33172/ . I don't think this has a clear spec ("Don't produce an error" is far too broad), and it's not clear what makes a haiku program a good haiku program?

Comment: As an illustration of the problems raised in point 2, consider that I can take any haiku I want, remove the characters `,.+-<>[]` (of which only the first two are likely to be present anyway) and claim it's a brainfuck program which does nothing. And before you edit to add a rule to prohibit that directly, let me emphasise the word **illustration**. The problem is far deeper, and I don't think it can be fixed. It certainly can't be papered over.

Answer (score 0):

## Pristine Pristige

A pristine program, as defined by Calvin'sHobbies, is

> a program that does not have any errors itself but will error if you modify it by removing any contiguous substring of **N** characters, where **0 < N < program length**.

Pristige is a language I designed in which *all* syntactically valid programs are pristine.

Pristige works just like [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), except every function requires a airity declaration at the beginning.  An airity of **n** is declared with **n** `.`s followed by a `|`.  For example the Brain-Flak program

```
({}())
```

Is equivalent to the Pristige Program

```
(..|{|}(|))
```

In addition Pristige requires that there is only one function at the top level of the program.  Meaning that

```
(.|{|}){.|(..|{|}[.|(|)])}
```

Is an invalid program.

To be absolutely concrete here is a grammar that spans all syntactically valid Pristige programs:

```
S → (A) : <A> : {A} : [A]
A → .AS : |
```

### Task

You must write a compiler from Pristige to Brain-Flak, that is itself a pristine program.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

### Rules

- You must either throw an error (or print `error` if your language cannot do so) if the inputted program is syntactically invalid.
- If the input is syntactically valid you must output an equivalent Brain-Flak program.  The simplest way to do this is to remove all instances of `.` and `|`, but you are not required to do so.
- You may use any default IO format.
- ***Your program must be a pristine program.  That means deleting any continuous substring must cause an error***

### Reference Implementation

Here will go an implementation I have not yet completed

### Test Cases

Here will go test cases

Comment: Surely we should print error if the program is syntactically **in**valid? Sort of unrelated, but is Pristige a mix of the words pristine and prestige?

Answer (score 0):

## Word Problem Generator [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

### Already exists [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/problem-generator/)!

Word problems can be a great way to test comprehension of concepts, but they are pain to write. That's why you need to make a program that takes an equation (or set of equations), and makes a word problem out of them. For example, if the input is `x+3=8`, you can output, `Mary has 3 more apples than Johnny. If Mary has 8 apples, how many does Johnny have?`

The best answers for this challenge will be able to handle many different types of equations and randomly generate a variety of unique word problems. It might be o.k. if your program creates non-sensical word problems, as long as they describe the input equation/equation set and people like them.

## Rules

- Submission must be no longer than 2000 bytes
- External files and URL's may be used to access word lists not specifically made for this challenge. You can also use libraries for parsing mathematical equations and sentence generation that were not specifically made for this challenge (WolframAlpha is acceptable). Inquire about other acceptable usage of external sources.
- **Golfing is encouraged.** Most popularity contests ask for readable code, but with a tight 2000 byte limit, I encourage golfing as much as possible  (even using a golfing language), so that you'll have enough bytes remaining to create interesting word problems.

## Examples

- `atan(x) = 5/4` => "At what angle should Jan hit the soccer ball to hit a target 5 feet high and 4 feet away?"
- `x+5 = y, 2(x-1) = y-1` => "Paul is 5 years older than Sally. Last year Paul was twice Sally's age. How old are Paul and Sally?"
- `x = 6^2/4^2`  => "How much more pizza is there in a 12 inch pizza than an 8 inch pizza?"

## Submission

With your submission, you include the types of equations/equation sets it can handle (we'll assume that `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` refer to constants and `t,u,v,w,x,y,z` refer to variables).

As an example, let's say your program can only make 1 type of word problem: "How long will it take for a boat with speed *a* to catch up to a boat with speed *b* that is distance *c* ahead of the first boat?" In that case, you write that your program only handles equations of the form `at = bt + c`, so people will know to only test it with things like `5t = 3t + 2` or `4t = 2t + 1`.

Furthermore, you should mention if your program can make multiple types of word problems for one type of equation/equation set. For example, an equation of the form `a + bx = c` could lead to word problems about the time it takes to get from one point to another, or the amount of a particular coin you need to reach a certain amount of money.

Likewise, mention other ways your program creates variety in generating word problems.

Finally, you can include some sample word problems your program has generated, and the equations they were for.

## Minimum Requirements

The most basic acceptable solution should handle at least 1 equation/equation set with at least 1 variable, 1 constant, and 1 mathematical operation. Such a minimal program might only handle equations of the form `x = a + 1`. It might output word problems like, "If Jerry has *a* apples, and he picks 1 more, how many does he have now?" Obviously, you should not strive for the bare minimum.

---

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet: [Tag Wiki for popularity contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info). As noted there, you should include an objective validity criterion. You already have some useful rules, but it's still not clear  me what the minimum requirement for an answer is. E.g. would handling only equations `x=1+2` suffice? What about only `x=3`.

Comment: @Laikoni ty, updated.

Comment: Personally, I dislike the scoring. Having a hard byte count limit discourages more verbose languages, but at the same time, byte count is not a factor in scoring. Also, I'm not sure [tag:popularity-contest] is the right choice here. I would either 1) Make it a [tag:code-golf] and impose strict requirements on what the program should be able to do, or 2) Make it a [tag:test-battery], where the score is the percentage of inputs that result in coherent output

Comment: @musicman523 I've thought about other formats than pop-con, but I think they all significantly reduce creativity. I don't have a perfect answer for byte count limit, but I think it is needed, otherwise people can spend forever hardcoding all sorts of words problems, which is not really what I'm looking for. Also, one tradeoff is the languages that are usually more verbose are the more established ones that also have more library access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of brainstorming a challenge. I'm not really paying attention to question format at the moment.

The challenge would be to generate and populate a Golf Scorecard.

The output would look something like this:

```
Hole    Par     Strokes Score
1       3       3       0
2       5       4       -1
3       4       5       1
4       3       4       1
5       4       4       0
6       5       3       -2
7       4       3       -1
8       3       5       2
9       5       5       0
Totals  36      36      0
```

A Par value would be generated by choosing a random number in [3, 4, 5].

A Stroke value would be generated by choosing a random number within some range (say -2/+2 or -3/+3) of Par. A Stroke can be no lower than 1.

`Score = Stroke - Par`

Total is adding up all the values in that column (not including Hole).

I'm wondering if it would be too much to ask to have the generated values be somewhat realistic (unlike my example output), in that Par values tend to be mostly 4, with about the same number between 3 and 5, and Stroke values tend to be close to or above Par, with it being very unlikely to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Comparing Strings

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

You will be given two non-empty strings containing printable ASCII. If their contents are exactly the same, output their contents. If their contents are different, output a third string. **This third string cannot be a substring of either string, and neither string can be a substring of it.**

## Test Cases

Test cases are quoted to show they are strings. Outputs marked with `*` indicate they are one of infinitely many possible outputs.

```
input, input -> output

"test", "test" -> "test"
"do", "don't" -> "dnut"*
"ye s", "yes" -> "false"*
"yes", "yes" -> "yes"
"maybe", "mayue" -> "false"*
"false", "false" -> "false"
"false", "true" -> "fatr"*
```

### Rules

- The inputs will be composed of only printable ASCII - that is, space to tilde. Your output should also be composed of only printable ASCII, but a trailing newline is allowed.
- Your algorithm may not make any assumption about the length of the inputs, except that they will not be empty.
- The output must be valid with probability 1; that is, you may generate random strings until one is valid, but you can't just output a random string and hope it's valid. [Source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123539/65836)
- Trailing newlines in output allowed (otherwise there will be no newlines - newlines are not in printable ASCII).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23860/65836) is the canonical string equal question, but it does not allow you to use string comparison.

Comment: Bro... Come on, at least 3 sentences.

Comment: Do you need to handle strings with new lines or spaces in them?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn added a bit more clarification :P what else is there to say?

Comment: @geokavel clarified

Comment: This needs more information, test cases and to actually be made into a challenge.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I forgot testcases - thank you. However, what else would I add to make it a challenge?

Comment: Usual boilerplate stuff, I'm sure something like this has been posted before too but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder OK, how's that? and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Better. I still don't like the challenge though it'll just lead to solutions like `s=>t=>s==t?s:s+t` Block ways of doing that and it'll be better

Comment: @TheLethalCoder hm, that was my idea for the harder challenge - that was why this says easy in the title. Do you think this is too trivial? I can just skip the easy one and go straight to the harder one.

Comment: I personally would. The easy one just leads to lots of FGITW answers. Yeah it'll probably be popular but boring.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder ok how's that?

Comment: Better but again I think you need to defend against the trivial cases i.e. `ab, cd` -> `bc` seems to be allowed and so does `ab, cd` -> `bb` yet they're both trivial changes to the inputs.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I think I can only go so far in blocking those, and with what you have, for the your first case, entering `aa, ab`, and for your second case, entering `aa, bc` would result in invalid output. Half the fun here will be "cracking" them.

Comment: Please explain the *"false", "false" -> "true"* case.

Comment: @Adám brainfart, thanks

Comment: @StepHen Somehow it bothers me that this challenge combines two unrelated challenges; compare and find a non-substring. I'd rather have a challenge that says *Given a list of non-empty strings, produce a non-empty string which is neither a substring of any input string, nor is any input string a substring of the output string.*

Comment: @Adám my original challenge was `Given two strings, output their value if they are exactly the same, and output a third value if they are different.` but you can look at the comments to see what happened to that. You're idea is good - I'll think on it, thanks.

Comment: What should you do if given an input that consists of all possible pairs of two characters (and another input that it isn't equal). That would make this impossible, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ppperry output would just be something like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: except that wouldn't be valid if the input contains `aa`. A pair of two character by my previous definition includes the same character repeated twice.

Comment: @ppperry the output cannot be a substring of the input, and the input cannot be a substring of the output. Not that they cannot share substrings.

Comment: And this reduces to a case of infinity, then. Still, should be a test case, to stop answers that assume a maximum length of output.

Comment: @ppperry not really - if the input is `aaabacad...` then `aaaa` is also acceptable output

Comment: But if the input is `aaaaaaabaaacaaadaaaeaaaf...aaazaaba...`, then you would need five characters of output. One can repeat this process however many times you want, thereby meaning that answers have to handle arbitrarily long strings.

Comment: @ppperry yes, that is correct - what languages don't naturally handle arbitrary length strings in output, but handle them in input?

Comment: None I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

## Can you generate this random sequence for me?

[Inspired by this question on Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/how-did-commodores-anti-microsoft-easter-egg-work)

I want to create a random generator that always returns a desired word. I desperately need this so I can hide some easter eggs. For <s>science</s> easter!

### Input

A word, either in string format or an array or vector of characters. You can assume all lowercase and only the regular characters `a-z`.

### Task

Write a full program or function that finds a seed such that when taking a random sample of letters, the desired word is output. The function then should return or save another full program or function that does the generating of this desired word.

### Rules

- The returned function of program should use random sampling to create the output, so it is not allowed to hardcode ([obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/))
- The output can be written to file in the case of a full program or returned.
- Hiding an easter eggs is easiest when there is little code, so the shortest code wins.
- If there is no seed that generates the required output, your program is allowed to run forever.
- Standard codegolf rules and loopholes apply.

### Example implementation:

```
> f <- function(string){
+     seed <- 1
+     set.seed(seed)
+     repeat{
+         seed <- seed + 1
+         set.seed(seed)
+         if(all(sample(letters, length(string), replace = TRUE) == string)){
+             break
+         }
+     }
+     generator <- function(){
+         set.seed(seed)
+         sample(letters, length(string), replace = TRUE)
+     }
+     return(generator)
+ }
> f("a")
function(){
        set.seed(seed)
        sample(letters, length(string), replace = TRUE)
    }
<bytecode: 0x000000001c83f2d8>
<environment: 0x000000001f906c20>
> g=f("a")
> g()
[1] "a"
> g()
[1] "a"
> g()
[1] "a"
```

Comment: So we're finding the seed to a pRNG that produces the correct output from a scrambled input? Have you actually managed to do this with any two none-trivial inputs? i.e. not just a few letters long?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I was initially thinking of doing dicerolls instead of words, since those should be easier, but I liked words better because they fit the related question better. The sample code did work for 5 letter words.

Answer (score 0):

## Arbitrary base conversion

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)

Given an integer `n` of any sign, output a list of digits of its representation in a given base `b` not in `-1, 0, 1`. If `b` is positive, `n` will be non-negative.

Rules:

- You may not use arbitrary base conversion built-ins like Jelly's `b` or 05AB1E's `в`.
- You may assume the input is valid, as above.
- All digits must be greater than or equal to `0` and strictly less than `b`.
- For zero you must return `[]`.

## Test cases

```
256, 10 -> [2, 5, 6]
256, -10 -> [3, 5, 6]
1000, 25 -> [1, 15, 0]
1000, -30 -> [2, 27, 10]
0, 300 -> [0]
1000, 1000 -> [1, 0]
18446744073709551615, 4 -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
18446744073709551615, -5 -> [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

## Sandbox

Is this a dupe?

Comment: I'd suggest `0` in any base be the empty array, so it doesn't need special handling from recursive solutions and the like.

Comment: @ETHproductions Let's see...well, `[0]` shouldn't actually need special-case handling if you put the sum check before the special cases...but otherwise I did consider `[]`.

Comment: We had [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76255/34531) which was closed as dupe of [that challange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69155/34531).

Comment: @nimi Hmm...from the title you would guess that it's about converting to bases 2..36 although that doesn't seem to be the case so not sure if this is a dupe or something.

Answer (score 0):

## Bomberman

Given an input Bomberman board `b`, use the following characters to define the different bomberman tiles:

- `X` denotes the outer boundary of the board.

  - `X` is always in each of the four corners of the board.
  - `X` may only be on the boundaries of the board.
- `-` denotes an empty space.

  - When a bomb blows up over an empty space, it replaces it with `*`; and may continue.
- `o` denotes a blocker that is breakable.

  - When a bomb blows up over a breakable blocker, it replaces it with `*`; and stops.
- `O` denotes an impenetrable blocker.

  - When a bomb reaches an impenetrable blocker, it stops prior to it.
- `0-9` describes a bomb of `n` power.

  - When a bomb explodes it explodes in a plus pattern.
  - A bomb of `0` strength would be: `*`.
  - A bomb of `1` strength would be: `* \n***\n *`
  - And so on... 1-indexing is not okay because that would make the 9 bomb a 10 bomb.

---

## Worked Example

An example board would be (without bombs):

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
X----------X
X-oo---O---X
X--------O-X
X--OoO-----X
X----------X
X--O-------X
X-------O--X
-----o------
X---------OX
X--O---o---X
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If we were to add some randomized bombs to this board we would see:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
X----------X
X-oo-1-O---X
X--------O-X
X--OoO--0--X
X---1------X
X--O-3-----X
X-------O--X
--4--o------
X---------OX
X--O-2-o---X
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This should, when input to your program, output the following explosion pattern:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
X----*-----X
X-oo***O---X # This didn't get blocked, it's just a small explosion.
X----*---O-X
X-*O*O--*--X # This destroyed a brittle block.
X-****-----X
X-*O*****--X # This got hard blocked.
X-*--*--O--X
*******---** # Notice how it wraps, because there's no boundary.
X-*--*----OX
X-*O****---X # This got hard-blocked.
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

---

## Example 1:

Input:

```
XX
XX
```

Output:

```
XX
XX
```

---

## Example 2:

Input:

```
X-O--X
-o2-o-
-1--1-
-o-2o-
X--O-X
```

Output:

```
X-O--X
-****-
******
-****-
X--O-X
```

---

## Example 3:

Input:

```
X     X
 OOOO
  1114


X     X
```

Output:

```
X    *X
 OOOO*
*******
  ****
     *
X    *X
```

---

## Rules

- Boards must be rectangular or square.
- Boards must have blockers on the corners of the rectangle/square.
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[awesome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awesome)[retro-ascii](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retro-ascii)

More examples, soon. Is this good? Sandbox? What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

## Make it night! <sup><sub>[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)</sub></sup>

You just went on vacation to see some scenery in the beautiful night. Unfortunately, your alarm clock malfunctions and when you wake up, it's daytime.

Your mother would like to see some photos, but you can only take pictures in the day. You would like to be able to convert these daytime pictures to pictures in the nighttime.

#### Challenge

Given an image taken in the daytime, process it and turn it into night time as best as you can.

Sometimes it might be hard to do, like images that have a sun, but you can write your algorithm to remove the sun or do something else.

#### Example

(I did this by hand, so it might not be that good)

[image: Original]

[image: Result]

#### Voting

Please vote accordingly to how well the algorithms perform.

- Is the sky dark like a night sky?
- Does the picture look photoshopped/edited?
- Are there vivid colors that shouldn't appear in the night?
- If you were showed both images, would you believe that there was no processing?

(If you have a suggestion, please comment.)

#### Test Cases

[image: Test case 1]

[image: Test case 2]

[image: Test case 3]

#### Winning

Since this is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), the answer with the highest score (upvotes minus downvotes) wins.

Comment: how to deal with the sun...

Comment: @HelkaHomba This URL is invalid or has expired.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Not sure, I'll think about it.

Comment: What would https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkx4V.jpg become?

Comment: @HelkaHomba This is a [tag:popularity-contest], so that depends on how your algorithm handles it. The better it does, the more votes you will probably get..

Comment: Won't this fall under the usual "No objective winning criteria" that pop cons have been falling under lately?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Fixed.

Comment: @OliverNi How? The voting criteria is still subjective and that's why recent ones have been closed.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder as I know, "highest score (upvotes minus downvotes)" is exactly the defaults for popularity-contest, at least it is written in the tag description: "A popularity contest is a competition where the answer with the highest vote tally (upvotes minus downvotes) wins."

Comment: @OliverNi Yeah you're winning criteria is fine. It's the subjective voting criteria I'm questioning.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Voting is subjective. You can't just tell someone to 'downvote if the answer has x pixels that are y units apart from all the four neighboring pixels' or something like that.

Comment: @OliverNi I know and isn't that the whole reason recent pop cons have been closed? Because the criteria people should vote on is subjective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63599/discussion-between-oliver-ni-and-thelethalcoder).

Comment: Provided you explicitly say what to do with the "dangerous" cases like the 'images with sun', this imo is a nice pop-contest but... you surely know well enough that pop-contests, almost always, don't garner much love here.

Comment: So... if you vertically flip any of those images your algorithm would fail?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Probably

Answer (score 0):

## Intertwined Polyglot

[polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program which when executed as language A, produces a *different* program in language B, which in turn produces the name of language A.  And the other way round (B to A to B).

```
+-----------+   Lang. A    +-----------+   Lang. B
| Program 1 | -----------> | Program 2 | -----------> "<Lang. A>"
|           |              +-----------+
|   Your    |              +-----------+
|  Program  | -----------> | Program 3 | -----------> "<Lang. B>"
+-----------+   Lang. B    +-----------+   Lang. A
```

### Rules

- The produced programs must be unique both from each other, and from the original program.
- Uniqueness is defined as at least one modified or moved printing character.  Example: `a bc` => `ab c` would **not** be considered unique, whereas `a bc`=> `a cb` would.
- The output may contain leading and/or trailing whitespace and/or newlines, so long as the language name is intact.
- Your program(s) may not take any input.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I couldn't find a matching question... but I really think this might be a dupe..

Comment: You should define "unique". Does 1 character difference count? Can it be a hidden character (CR,...)?

Comment: @officialaimm That's what I thought too, but I had no luck finding it either

Comment: @Goufalite I would say yes to a single character, but I'm not sure about whitespace. For some languages it's integral, but others will ignore it

Comment: I believe [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2582/42545) is the duplicate you guys are thinking of. cc @officialaimm

Comment: @ETHproductions Nope, not that one... I don't even know if there is a dupe, I just doubt there might be one..

Comment: The "And the other way round" should be emphasized more. On my first read, I though only A to B to A was necessary. An example would solve this and make the challenge easier to understand overall.

Comment: @fireflame241 Does the diagram I've added help to ease understanding?

Comment: @MTCoster absolutely. However, it looks like Program 1 and Your Answer are different. Remove the dividing line?

Answer (score 0):

## Implement a basic two-dimensional esolang [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There are hundreds of two-dimensional stack-based esoteric programming languages out there, and lots of them follow a very similar syntax:

```
v redirect instruction pointer down
> redirect instruction pointer right
^ redirect instruction pointer up
< redirect instruction pointer left
/ redirect instruction pointer: up -> right, right -> up, left -> down, down -> left
\ redirect instruction pointer: up -> left, left -> up, right -> down, down -> right
0 push 0 to the stack. 1 pushes 1, ... 9 pushes 9.
A push 10 to the stack. B pushes 11, ... F pushes 15.
: duplicate the top stack value
~ swap top two stack values (all languages implement this as a different character)
i read input as a ASCII character and push to stack
o print the top of stack as an ASCII character
n read input as integer and push to stack
u print the top of stack as an integer
+ increment the top of stack
- decrement the top of stack
! jump over the next command
; stop execution
```

Almost all two-dimensional esolangs contain more commands, but for the sake of simplicity, the one we're writing will contain only the above.

---

## Specification

The stack should be able to hold at least 30,000 values. You may pick any integer size (e.g. 32-bit, 64-bit, unbounded, etc) for stack values.

The instruction pointer should start moving right from the top left corner of the source code, and should wrap upon exiting the playing field, meaning that this code will be an infinite loop:

```
<^
v>
```

First, `<` will be reached, pointing the IP off to the left.
The IP will wrap around to the right, continuing left, and hit the `^`, directing it up.
Then it will wrap, hit the `>` and travel right, wrap, hit the `v` and travel down, wrap, hit the `<`, and start over.

Answer (score 0):

## Is Effort Inversely Correlated with Upvotes?

*Inspired by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39538057#39538057) chat message and the subsequent conversation*

### Introduction

PPCG is infamous (famous?) for it's short golfing language answers that are showered with upvotes. But, are these short answers full of hard-core golfing, or are they just a few builtins that work? Do these answers take effort, and deserve upvotes, or are upvotes and effort inversely correlated?

### The Challenge

*To get some variables out of the way, x=effort, and y=votes*

Your challenge is, given a question ID, output `A` if the question has a strong positive correlation between effort and votes, `B` if it has a weak correlation between efforts and votes, or `C` if it has a strong negative correlation between effort and votes. `A` may be any value never given as `B` or `C`, `B` may be any value never given as `A` or `C`, and `C` may be any value never given as `A` or `B` (You doubt have to have consistent values across runs, but the set of values for `A` must not intersect with `B` or `C`, etc.).

#### Defining Effort

Effort is an awfully complex concept, but for this challenge we will grossly simplify it to the number of `significant edits`. `significant edits`, in this context, will be the number of edits, by the question author, that occurred more than 1 minute after the previous edit (initial posting, in this case, counts as an edit).

#### Defining Votes

Votes is `upVotes` - `downVotes`.

#### Defining Correlation

For the sake of simplicity, will we use the least-squares regression line as our correlation model. If `R^2` (the determination coefficient) is less than `.3` (e.g. < 30% of the variation is explained by the model), we will say that there is weak correlation. If `R^2` is greater than or equal to `.3`, we will say that the correlation is strong. Negative vs. positive correlation must be determined from the sign of `R` (the correlation coefficient).

#### What Points?

The data points that should be included in your regression are points of the form `(votes, effort)` for each answer in the given question.

#### Test Cases

//TODO

#### Specifics

- For the purposes of this challenge, you may access the `api.stackexchange.com` website. You may not shorten the URL with any out-of-language utilities (e.g. tinyurl, but you can still compress it if your language supports compression)
- You may not violate any [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You may take input and give output in any [reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- You should exclude community wikis from your calculations

## Meta

- Question is a work in progress
- Anyone have a good title
- How valid are my statistics?
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

Comment: @programmer5000 okay

Comment: "*number of edits greater than 5 characters*" counted how? Levenshtein distance with substitution counted as 1? (This is a terrible proxy for effort: apart from anything else, adding strikeout to record a one-byte improvement would take you past the threshold, even if the improvement was suggested in comments and required no effort on the OP's part).

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's intentional (the strikeout), but I agree that's it's a bad proxy for effort.. I'll try and create a better one...

Comment: @PeterTaylor updated definition of effort, is it better or worse?

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) ...?

## Fork for *n* times

[image: -bash: fork: HE COMES]

*TL;DR: fork up to `n` times, than hang forever*

[Relevant chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/fork-bomb)

Your challenge is to make a program / function that calls itself twice or uses some other method of creating copies of itself that create copies of itself, etc.

However, to avoid crashing the system, **your program limits itself before it forks to death**. Given an input `n`, your program should stop forking when it has `n` total copies of itself (including itself), and keep running forever with `n` total copies of itself.

---

## Meta

- Under-specified?
- Is the min of 500 good?
- Tags?
- Better title?

Comment: It's not exactly a dupe of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24485/31716), but that one is the same spirit, and it's closed and locked, so I wouldn't expect this to be well received. Also see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4829/31716) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8877/31716)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem see edits

Answer (score 0):

## Code the beach on the beach (heavily WIP)

The Gods of the Sea have seen your coding ability and asked you to rewrite their beach-generating program.

## Code the beach

This program will take no input and, in this order:

- Print sand (`.`)
- Print ocean waves (`~`)
- Print crabs (`>.<`)
- Print seagulls (`-v-`)

This program will be run by the Gods of the Sea. They will run it once a day and will want a different beach every time they run it, so the beach items should be generated (pseudo)randomly.

To avoid this beach becoming overloaded, there should be:

- Between five and eight crabs
- Between three and seven seagulls
- Between eighty and one hundred grains of sand
- Eighty ocean waves

Your program should create the beach just as the Gods' existing program does. It will first draw the sand at the bottom of the screen, in the last three lines. Example sand:

```
. .. .. . . ... . ... ..  . ..  .... .. . ... . .. . .. . . .. . .. . . .... ...
  .. . .. .. .. .. ... .   ..  .. ... ...  .   .   ....... .... ...... ... .
. . . .. .. ...... ... .. ......... .  .... .. . . . . ... .. .. . . . ...
```

Then the waves will be printed, starting from the leftmost character in the fourth-to-last line. The point where the waves meet the sand should vary by at most one character, and waves should never go off the screen. All water that is not curling in a wave will cover the sand, so there can be no sand under the water. Example waves:

**TODO: Add example waves**

Crabs should be spawned in the last four lines and cannot be spawned on waves, because if they were, they would be quickly sucked under and disappear.

Seagulls may be spawned anywhere, and should be evenly distributed to the best of your pRNG's ability.

## On the beach

The Gods were born in ancient times, so they're still using VGA; their terminal has 80x25 characters for output, as does their text editor - which is so old it does not support scrolling. Your program will have to fit in this text editor, so it will need to be small.

The Gods do not yet have the internet, so you'll have to write your program on the beach in a location they can see it. Unfortunately, the only convenient place at the moment is a very small sandbar on the Oregon coast. Waves occasionally reach this spot. To make sure you have enough time write the entire program before it's washed away, it will need to be *as small as possible.*

Furthermore, since the Gods are so far away, some characters written in the sand are indistinguishable. Gods are good at guessing, so if they see a character that looks like another they'll get it right, but another character that looks similar to the character they guessed will be assumed to be said previous character. So if a `l` is present in the source before an `I`, the Gods will see two `l`s.

Here are the lookalikes:

- `o` and `O`
- `l` and `I` and `|`
- `:` and `;`
- `"` and `'`

The Gods don't have the technology to easily use Unicode characters, so you'll have to give them a lot of help. Each non-ASCII character you use will cost **5 bytes** to describe it to them.

Comment: I'm not sure if the lookalike characters and penalty for non-ASCII characters is necessary. Drawing the beach, random placement and number of objects, and constrained placement of objects sounds like enough to me.

The 80x25 hard constraint also seems superfluous. A line width limit of 80 keeps the idea, but would still allow for golfing in more verbose languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Numbers to Algorithms

Another horrible part of Cubically is attempting to print numbers when the notepad is occupied. Since you can't add up existing faces, the integer (or ASCII value) you have to print needs to be on one single face.

The maximum value you can store on one Cubically face is 45. This isn't great, but it's better than nothing. Your challenge is to write a program that automates the process of getting the values 0-45 onto the top face.

Your program will take an input number `n` and produce a Cubically code snippet as output. This Cubically snippet should achieve the task of getting all integers on the top face to sum up to `n`. If you don't yet know how Cubically works, go check out the [repo](//git.io/Cubically). Here's a run-down of all you need to know.

Cubically is my esolang based on a Rubik's Cube. Its 3x3x3 memory cube is initialized like this (without the comments on the right):

```
   000
   000          top face
   000
111222333444    left, front, right, and back faces, respectively
111222333444
111222333444
   555
   555          down face
   555
```

It uses quarter turn notation, so `RRLL` turns the cube to look like this:

```
   505
   505
   505
111424333242
111424333242
111424333242
   050
   050
   050
```

Now the sum of the top face is 30. So if `n` is 30, `RRLL` would be a valid output.

In addition to quarter turn notation, you can send a subscript number to face turns to mean "turn the xth layer inwards from the [face] face, where x is the subscript number". So `R1` would turn the cube to look like this:

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)? [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## JS, 44 bytes

## Here's a list of languages & byte counts from PPCG:

```
Jelly, 27 bytes
Mathematica, 174 bytes
Scala, 91 bytes
05AB1E, 12 bytes
dc, 13 bytes
Python 2, 115 bytes
V, 25 bytes
Charcoal, 48 bytes
Jelly, 10 bytes
Haskell, 25 bytes
MATL, 14 bytes
x86-16, 43 bytes
Emoji, 50 bytes
Pyth, 9 bytes
C, 38 bytes
JavaScript, 69 bytes
R, 73 bytes
Node.js, 70 bytes
Ly, 7 bytes
Japt, 7 bytes
Java, 2777 bytes
Husk, 18 bytes
Beatnik, 148 bytes
APL, 10 bytes
Powershell, 127 bytes
Python 3, 111 bytes
Ruby, 38 bytes
Cubically, 1231 bytes
C++, 292 bytes
Common, 98 bytes
Swift 4, 63 bytes
Axiom, 91 bytes
Groovy, 7 bytes
Bitmap, 160 bytes
Batch, 86 bytes
Perl 5, 34 bytes
Pyke, 7 bytes
Java, 182 bytes
PHP, 1 bytes
C#, 163 bytes
Processing, 85 bytes
Tcl, 66 bytes
PowerShell, 11 bytes
LOGO, 33 bytes
axo, 22 bytes
Excel, 37 bytes
TXR Lisp, 76 bytes
Alice, 17 bytes
Moorhens, 716 bytes
PHP, 2943 bytes
Python, 79 bytes
QBIC, 25 bytes
D, 65 bytes
Emojicode, 50 bytes
REXX, 46 bytes
BBC, 70 bytes
Retina, 24 bytes
Bash, 74 bytes
Cubix, 28 bytes
cQuents, 7 bytes
J, 90 bytes
AHK, 110 bytes
Mathics, 46 bytes
RProgN 2, 8 bytes
SOGL, 36 bytes
Röda, 36 bytes
><>, 238 bytes
QuadR, 32 bytes
C#, 289 bytes
Bash, 385 bytes
JS, 2823 bytes
C, 14 bytes
HTML, 132 bytes
Ruby, 40 bytes
JS, 130 bytes
Gaia, 17 bytes
TI-BASIC, 17 bytes
Befunge, 10 bytes
Ruby 2.4, 53 bytes
Pari/GP, 21 bytes
Actually, 10 bytes
APL, 4 bytes
TXR, 74 bytes
Sage, 102 bytes
Grime, 28 bytes
Ruby, 101 bytes
C++17, 71 bytes
Perl, 41 bytes
CPython, 25984 bytes
SmileBASIC, 43 bytes
WendyScript, 50 bytes
Python, 2969 bytes
Clojure, 156 bytes
Lost, 57 bytes
C++, 19 bytes
Brachylog, 4 bytes
Octave, 25 bytes
C#, 123 bytes
Magneson, 102 bytes
Brain-Flak, 36 bytes
```

**This list will change before this challenge is posted.**

## Your challenge

Look at the program before you. It will print something like `JS, 23 bytes`. That means that **you must use JS as your language**.

Then pick a line from the list. Let's say you pick `LOGO, 33 bytes`. That means that **you must print `LOGO, 33 bytes` in JS**.

Because `LOGO, 33 bytes` is the **44th line, your byte count modulo the number of languages in the list (there are 100) must equal 44.**

The three restrictions:

- You must use JS
- You must print `LOGO, 33 bytes`
- Your byte count modulo 100 must be 44

So a valid submission might be:

```
x=>"LOGO, 33 bytes"//just wasting some bytes
```

Then, after your submission, **you add the list from the last answer to your answer. Then, you remove `Logo, 33 bytes` from the list**: (in your answer, not the question)

That's **the language you used, and the byte count you used**. Add it to the bottom. Dupes are OK.

Your answer will look like this:

> ## JS, 44 bytes
>
> ```
> x=>"LOGO, 33 bytes"//just wasting some bytes
> ```
>
> #### Here's the new list:
>
> ```
> (Insert the list here, and remove `Logo, 33 bytes`)
> ```
>
> **The next submission must use Logo**.

Note that the list will continually get smaller, making the challenge harder.

---

## Meta

- Winning criterion? Last answer? Second-to-last? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
- Unclear?
- Dupe?

Comment: @BusinessCat Ok, I think I'll restrict to TIO-only langs when I update the list. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: 1. In the interests of clarity, when picking arbitrary numbers make them different. 44 seems to occur in two different contexts in the example. 2. The bit about adding to the list is unclear. Are you saying that after submitting an answer, you must edit the question? That will (a) cause conflicts; (b) (I think) cause the question to become community wiki quite quickly; (c) break the example. And to accomplish what? 3. Expanding on that previous question: what is the motivation? Even answer-chaining questions benefit from a clear motivation for the core task.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I hope the recent edit clarified 2., and I will use a different list when I post this (1.)

Comment: @programmer5000 `Röda`

Comment: @programmer5000 Thanks, that clears up adding to the list.

Comment: You probably want to remove from the list either what language was previously printed or what language you're currently printing, that way the list remains modulo 100.

Comment: I think that every [tag:answer-chaining] question so far has some mechanism to make it increasingly harder to extend the chain. With this one it seems to get easier to extend the chain rather than harder. Is this not a fundamental flaw?

Comment: The way I read it, every answerer removes one item from the list and adds one item to the list, so it doesn't get shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## Help Me Catch Up With xkcd! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

I definitely enjoy xkcd, and you, as a code golfer, most likely enjoy it as well. However, I often find that I won't check the website for a while and there will be a lot to read! So, I want to make a solution for that. In proper code golf fashion.

---

### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program which, when run, will check for a new xkcd and, if there is a new comic (in other words, it is different from the one when the program last ran), output the text "`There's a new xkcd out!`". Use this method to check:

1. When the program is run, check if there is a file named `.xkcd` in the user's home directory. If not, create the file, which will contain the title of the current xkcd comic, then exit.
2. If the file `.xkcd` *does* exist in the user's home directory, the program will check if the title of the xkcd comic on the front page of xkcd.com is the same as the one in `.xkcd`. If it is, the program will exit and do nothing else. However, if the titles *aren't* the same, the program will output the specified text, change the contents of `.xkcd` to the new title, then exit.

If you have any other methods, tell me about them.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: This seems rather close to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91847/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor Dupe?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Also, how could I distinguish it and add something unique so that it isn't marked as a dupe?

Comment: My opinion in general is that when a question is a borderline dupe it's more productive to ditch it and try to think of a radically different question than to try to bisect to find the minimal sufficient difference. I don't see anything about this particular topic which would make it an exception to that general rule.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Where in the world am I?

### Original Challenge

This challenge has a single aim, given no input, print out the user's current location, with a minimum of the following info:

- City
- Country

So any of the following are allowed:

- "London, England"
- "Eifel Tower, Paris, France"
- ["London", "England"]
- {"country": "Scotland", "city": "Edinburgh"}

The following are not allowed:

- [51.5074, 0.1278]
- {"country": "Scotland", "city": "Edinburgh", ISP: "EE"}

Do not show the user's IP or ISP name, or any extra output.

Standard code golf rules apply

Good luck, and have fun!

### Reason for limits

- No ISP or IP

  - Stops just using ipinfo.io
- No long and lat

  - [This has already been a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119078/err-where-am-i)

### Thanks

programmer5000 - Suggesting to post here after original was deleted

caird coinheringaahing - Lon and Lat rules

Comment: Is returning a list of geo-cordinates allowed? You might want to clarify that in the question

Comment: This has a number of issues with ill-defined cases. In particular, the following are not addressed: (A) my location is unambiguously in a given country, but there's no city within several hours' drive; (B) my location is unambiguously not inside any country; (C) the territorial ownership of my location is disputed; (D) it's not clear what the name of the country is (where your example of Edinburgh is a good one: if Scotland is correct, is UK incorrect? How about dependencies, colonies, etc?)

Comment: In addition, it contradicts itself over whether `{"country": "Scotland", "city": "Edinburgh"}` is allowed or not; and it is not very testable. To make this a good challenge I would recommend taking latitude and longitude as inputs and providing a complete and unambiguous specification of exactly what the output string should be such that any incorrect answer can be shown to be incorrect with a test case which it fails.

Comment: TBH, if someone was onboard the International Space Station and decided to take time out to complete my code golf challenge I would take it as a compliment. For international waters I would be OK with an answer that pointed towards that. For ones with multiple answers / disputed it would probably be reasonable to accept multiple answers, but there may be issues with this I have not foreseen.

Comment: RE: The contradiction, this was an omission I hope I have fixed now

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue more generally? I know my answer is a bit vague and not built into the question

Comment: Is this challenge good to go, needs changes, or not of use?

Answer (score 0):

## The source of pi

<sub>Inspired by an [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest#Examples)  entry.</sub>

### Task

As you all know, pi is a constant that represents the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter.

Using the dimensions of your own source code, approximate pi to at least two decimal places.

That is, your source code should read itself to obtain both circumference and diameter, then output the ratio.

For example, if your code is:

```
 AB
CDEF
 GH
```

Your circumference is `14` and your diameter is `4`.

For the purposes of this challenge, let diameter equal the larger of the height or width of your code.

### Rules

- Take no input
- Hardcoded values for pi are not allowed
- Output pi to at least two decimal places (e.g., `3.14` and `3.1415` are both acceptable outputs)
- Answers can be either whole programs or functions

### Notes

Answers with higher precision values are acceptable.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

---

### Meta

Looking for suggestions of a better title.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what "*Using the area of your own source code*" means. I could do some pretty "standard" approximation algorithm to fullfill your rules.

Comment: Wouldn't `print(3.14)` work? It isn't hardcoding pi, as pi isn't `3.14`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - I've updated the specification.  Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - I've updated the specification. Hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

## Paint with Pride!

**Task:** Output a 6 banded version of the [*pride* flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag_(LGBT_movement))

**Details:**

The flag consists of 6 bands of colour, each band is rectangular, and all are the same size which is 9x1 units (WxH) . These bands are stacked one on top of each other in the order shown to form a flag that is 9x6 units in size.

The output scale can be chosen by the participant, but all components must be in those ratios, that is, an output must have an aspect ratio which is a multiple of 3:2.

The hexadecimal values and relative positions of the colours are as below:

[image: Full size]

Or from top to bottom RGB `(255,0,0)`, `(255,153,0)`, `(255,255,0)`, `(0,153,0)`, `(0,0,255)`, `(204,0,153)`

A minimal version would look like this:

[image: Min size]

**Acceptable output:**

[Output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/68602) to screen or as a file in a commonly accepted image format is allowed, ascii art is however not.

*Sandbox notes:*

*[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/136927/68602), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64140/68602)*

*I chose this flag because I think the rainbow provides potential for an additional mathematical element*

*I'm not sure whether to include a minimum size limit, such as the one for drawing the french flag, as perhaps the small output size allows hardcoded answers to succeed (which I don't really want) - any advice?*

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75395/66833) unfortunately

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Shoot, all that time searching for "Pride" and "Flags", forgot to search for rainbow! Perhaps this is significant-enough a variant (rectangle vs bow) that it will allow for different approaches though. I'm not sure what the etiquette is, but I guess I'll leave this up for a while longer and let votes tell me whether it is too much of a duplicate to post.

Comment: personally, I would close as a duplicate, but if you want to keep it here and see otherwise, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

## "Square Root of Pi(e)"

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

A pie (r=3) is drawn as such:

```
  @@
 @@@@
@@@@@@
 @@@@
  @@
```

Pretending that it's a perfect circle, the square root of such a pie would be `sqrt(PI*32)` = `3sqrt(PI)` ~ 5.317. Now take a square out of the pie, whose area is closest to the square root of the pie. In this case it would be a square of area 4. Therefore, you can output:

```
  @@
 @@@@
@@  @@
 @  @
  @@
```

Yep, I took a square out of the pie, how do you like that?

---

**r=7**

```
      @@
     @@@@
    @@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@ 
 @@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@
    @@@@@@
     @@@@
      @@
```

7*sqrt(PI) ~ 12.407. Closer to 3x3 than 4x4 square.

```
      @@
     @@@@
    @@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@ 
 @@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@   @@@
  @@@@@   @@
   @@@@   @
    @@@@@@
     @@@@
      @@
```

#### Specifications:

1. Input will be only a "pie" with integer radius of at least two. As you can see, the longest row has **2r** `@`s, and the smallest rows have 2 `@`s.
2. You can use a symbol other than "@".
3. You can take a square out of the inside or the edge.
4. Approximate PI to at least 3.14.

**Bonus**: Valid answers that are in a language with food-related name get a free upvote!

Comment: You don't ever define How one forms the pie shape, and in general you seem to be lacking specification.

Answer (score 0):

## The Best Question

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

This site gets a variety of questions: the good, the bad, the ugly. However, I've noticed some patterns that I think will help us find **The Best Question** (of a given week).

### Procedure

You are given a date in a human-readable format of your choice as input. You need to find the best question from that week. The week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday. Click on the link for a valid query to use if the input is [Aug 31, 2017](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=100&fromdate=2017-08-27&todate=2017-09-02&order=asc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=codegolf&run=true). Note that when using the API without a key you can use UNIX epoch time or YYYY-MM-DD to specify the dates (info [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates)). Since this site gets only about 45 questions a week, you can assume that no more than 100 questions will be asked in a given week in order to avoid pagination.

### Scoring

First of all, closed questions are **disqualified**. Next, here is the formula for Question Rating (QR)<sup>1</sup>, given Question Score (S) and Number of Answers (A):

[image]

The thinking is that there are two kinds of questions that undeservedly get a very high question score: 1) the ones that are easy and get a lot of answers, and 2) the ones that are so difficult that they get few or no answers. I've determined that the best questions have a QuestionScore:Answer ratio of about 3:2.

### Output

All you have to do is output the full URL of the question that got the best question score. If multiple tie, you can output them all or just one.

### Example

Here's a list of 8 imaginary questions, with their question score followed by the number of answers they received, and their resulting QR:

```
1. +6, 23A -> -0.333
2. +10, 0A -> 7.78
3. +8, 4A -> 7.56
4. -2, 6A -> -4.44
5. +5, 3A [closed] -> DQ
6. +20 2A -> 16.22
7. +24, 40A -> 16
8. +15, 14A -> 13.67
```

So the winner is question 6. Output its URL.

### Note

You don't need to handle the rare edge case when there are no valid questions in a given week.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: This scoring system is just a joke.</sub>

---

Suggestions on formula and other stuff welcome.

Comment: Is that `abs((QuestionScore/2)-Answers)/2` or `abs(QuestionScore/(2-Answers))/2`?

Comment: Hopefully this looks a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

## Extend the Pattern

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)
Given a raster image with a lattice pattern, extend it to twice the size of the input image in both directions.

#### Details

The input image is a section of an infinite repeating pattern defined by two vectors `u=(ux,uy),v=(vx,vy)` with integer entries, that are linearly independent. This means that both vectors are nonzero and do not point in the same direction. The pattern is defined such that the pixel at a point `p = (x,y)` has the exact same colour as the pixel at

```
q := p + s*u + t*v
```

for every integer `s,t`.
This means if you know the colours of the pixels within the *fundamental parallelogram* `Z = { s*u + t*v | s in [0,1),t in [0,1)}` and corresponding vectors `u,v` you can extend the pattern to an arbitrary size.
The goal of this challenge is finding the pattern and extend the image.

[image]

#### Specs

- You can take the input image in any non-compressed image format that allows for at least 3 colours, this includes e.g. matrices, 2d arrays or strings.
- The input method must match the output method. That means if you read a `.png` file as input, you must also write a `.png` file as output, or if you take the input via console, you must also print the output via console e.t.c.

#### Examples

(to be added...)

Comment: Is there freedom to choose which quadrant of the output image corresponds to the input image?

Comment: You need to add some harder test-cases - at present you can just check for overlaps, tile "infinitely" then crop.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good question, I think I will leave the direction arbitrary.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think this method works in any case, or do you have an example in mind where this does not work?

Comment: @flawr One where there's less than one copy of the parallelogram... wait, that wouldn't prevent the overlap technique from working.

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a Brainfuck compresser.

The eso-lang [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) only has 8 instructions that do something: `+-><[],.` so in theory you could represent them in 3 bits. You could store 8 instructions in 24 bits or 3 bytes.

### BrnFck

This is compressed brainfuck an instruction will be represented by its bits.

1. `+` : 000
2. `-` : 001
3. `>` : 010
4. `<` : 011
5. `[` : 100
6. `]` : 101
7. `,` : 110
8. `.` : 111

This is a language counted in bits, 8 bits is 1 byte depending on the challenge you may round up or keep a decimal.

### The goal

Write the shortest program that can compile any inputted brainfuck code to BrnFck code:

- You can choose how you output it, byte,bit/boolean arrays and output streams are all acceptable. Just printing ASCII-letters is too.
- You can do anything (including crash) if the input isn't valid code or contains a non-bf character.

And can compile the BrnFck code back to Brainfuck (or any other language (except BrnFck)). You may ask which way you want to compile or write 2 separate programs/functions and sum their scores.

If you post the code online (for example as an answer) this should automatically allow BrnFck as a language in all future challenges!

### Scoring

If you use brainfuck you can divide your bytes by 2.

If you use BrnFck you can divide your bytes by 4 (let's get some recursion going here).

1 bit will be counted as 0.125 bytes (please put both in the title) so decimal byte scores are allowed.

### Tags

brainfuck,code-golf,...

Comment: This encoding doesn't really work since no sensible architecture allows partial bits. Since each 3 bit word is already used, there is no way to distinguish say `,+.` from `,+..` if you happen to fill the remaining bits in that way. That said, it isn't totally required for the question for this to work. Otherwise, the bonuses and scoring are needless and confusing, so I'd recommend removing them.

Comment: Nearly every byte score on PPCG is decimal (base 10): I think you mean that *fractional* byte scores are possible. To deal with the padding problem, I suggest that you specify that where one or two padding bits are required, `0` should be used; and where three to seven are required, the padding should be `101` followed by as many `0`s as necessary. Since `[]` must be balanced, this allows unambiguous detection of the padding on decompression. Then make sure to include a test case which ends in `]` and requires no padding...

Answer (score 0):

## Program that allows the user to edit it's own source code

Write a program that displays and allows the user to view, edit and save it's own source code.

- If no edits are made, the output file should be the same as the program, and hence executing it should allow the user to edit the program's code again. (ie a quine)
- If the code has been edited in a sensible way, running the program again should display the *edited* code. The definition of 'sensible' is left flexible to prevent this being impossible - as the source code can be edited, a user can obviously edit the program in such a way that it no longer displays it's source code.

The standard quine rule applies: no reading the source file directly.

---

**Additional Notes and things to consider:**

- How robust is your program? What percentage of your program can be edited (sensibly) before it stops displaying it's own source or saving the edits you made.
- Both overwriting and saving with a different filename are valid ways for the program to save it's new code
- If it is a compiled language, the program does not have to invoke the compiler or do the compiling itself after saving.
- This is a code *challenge* not code *golf*. Robustness, interface and 'coolness' of the solution are favoured over brevity.
- Extra, uh, points(?!) if your program can identify errors in the quine before saving.

---

Is this a feasible challenge? Does it need clarification?

Comment: If the only winning-criteria is "Percentage of the characters which can be changed without breaking it" then the answerer can arbitrarily pad their score with an irrelevant string if their language has very versatile quining capabilities. The other things "favored" only really count if it's a [tag:popularity-contest] and challenges with that tag are discouraged.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to score it? I can't think of any cross-language methods.

Comment: Currently you are scoring it as (characters that can change / total), You could square or cube the total to incentivise golfing, that way padding can only hurt you.  However you want to watch out for very short programs that make little effort to complete the task but by virtue of their shortness are highly scoring.

Answer (score 0):

## Do the line segments cross?

Description: Today, we're going to do some geometry: We have two line segments and want to find out where they cross! A point is a pair of two integers being the x and y coordiantes of said point. If your calculations result in non-integers, you continue with the integer closest to your result.

I/O: You are given the two segments in form of 8 integers representing the 4 end points. You may take them in the order that fits you best, but you have to state the ordering. The output consisting of the point where the lines intersect, or `null`, an empty string or something similar, but no undefined behavior. You may use STDOUT, a file etc. to write your output.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Can I take 4 tuples `(x,y)` instead?

Comment: Of course. Are you golfing in Haskell?

Comment: I'm not golfing now. Many languages have tuples.

Comment: This is just a subset of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38614/42963).

Comment: Only up to a certain degree. The challenge you mentioned is ok with a truthy/falsey value. That makes a difference in chosing your "algorithm".

Answer (score 0):

## Prime Number Locator

Given a prime number `p > 1`, determine at what index `p` appears in [A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040).

- You may 0 or 1 index, meaning 2 can return 0 or 1.
- If you are given a non-prime number you must return -1.

  - If you are 1-indexing you may return 0 instead, or still return -1.
- Your time complexity must be less than `O(n)`: Please explain your calculations in the answer.

First 10 return values (0-indexed):

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
[0, 1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)[prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime): Reduce your byte-count to win.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94348/prime-counting-function)

Comment: @H.PWiz, I'd call that a dupe; the count is the index.

Comment: @Shaggy This one is [tag:restricted-complexity] though

Comment: `o(n)` is impossible: this isn't a problem which can be solved without reading all of the input. If that were relaxed to `O(n)` I think this would fit the "Too broad" close criterion because a properly explained answer would be a (very good) doctoral thesis. The current state-of-the-art algorithms are `O(2^(2n/3) + epsilon)`, so a polynomial algorithm would already be impressive, and a linear one would be astounding.

Answer (score 0):

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) [tag:H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ]

## Parse HTML with regex!

Alternate titles:

## [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/6560716)

## H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ - Parse HTML with regex

## Background

**[Don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6560716)** It always fails and sometimes summons Cthulhu.

But, because PPCG is different, we will parse HTML with regex.

And not easy, beginner HTML. HTML with comments, attributes with no quotes, HTML in script tags not commented out and much more. Can you write a regex to parse that?

## The challenge

Your challenge is to make a regex that matches valid HTML tags. Don't match comments, don't match invalid HTML, don't match HTML in comments, just match valid HTML tags. Each full regex match is one HTML tag.

Your input HTML will never contain commas. You will try to get the most points possible by successfully matching the HTML tags and not the text in as many inputs as possible. Whoever gets the most points wins. Please say at least 1 regex flavor that your regex works with.

You are not allowed to use regex features to execute language code. ([Sorry, Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression))

The length of your regex is irrelevant, this is not code golf.

## Test cases

Here are the test cases. You can also find them at https://hastebin.com/raw/mikaxakipe.txt.

```
1,1,<b>HTML!</b>,<b>,</b>
2,1,<i><b>HTML</b></i>,<i>,<b>,</b>,</i>
3,1,a < b implies b > a,
4,2,<img alt=text>Img,<img alt=text>
5,2,<a href = "http://example.com">Example Domain</a>,<a href = "http://example.com">,</a>
6,2,<hr><br/>,<hr>,<br/>
7,2,<div id ="hi" class="what">What</div>,<div id ="hi" class="what">,</div>
8,3,<a>fake</>,<a>
9,3,Self-closing <img src = "self-closing.jpeg" />?,<img src = "self-closing.jpeg" />
10,3,<self-closed/>O_O<unclosed>,<self-closed/>,<unclosed>
11,3,Do<yOU>like<LoTs>of<mIXeD><cAsE>?,<yOU>,<LoTs>,<mIXeD>,<cAsE>
12,3,Wh<a b='c'd="e">at?,<a b='c'd="e">
13,3,Hi<p data-hi=3>hihihi</p>,<p data-hi=3>,</p>
14,4,<a"oops">Oops,
15,5,<!-- <b><!--hi--><i>,<i>
16,5,<0>NOT VALID</0><h0>fine</h0>,<h0>,<h0>
17,5,<a a=b<>what</a>,<a a=b<>,</a>
18,6,<!-- <b><!--hi--><i>-->,<i>
19,7,<how><deep can><your nesting nesting><level></level></go>?<how>Deep</how><can><your>nesting <go x=? j><how><deep can><your nesting nesting><level></level></go>?<how>Deep</how><can><your>nesting <go x=? j><how><deep can><your nesting nesting><level></level></go>?<how>Deep</how><can><your>nesting <go x=? j></your></can></your></deep></how></your></can></your></deep></how></your></can></your></deep></how>,<how>,<deep can>,<your nesting nesting>,<level>,</level>,</go>,<how>,</how>,<can>,<your>,<go x=? j>,<how>,<deep can>,<your nesting nesting>,<level>,</level>,</go>,<how>,</how>,<can>,<your>,<go x=? j>,<how>,<deep can>,<your nesting nesting>,<level>,</level>,</go>,<how>,</how>,<can>,<your>,<go x=? j>,</your>,</can>,</your>,</deep>,</how>,</your>,</can>,</your>,</deep>,</how>,</your>,</can>,</your>,</deep>,</how>
20,7,<plaintext><b></plaintext>,<plaintext>,</plaintext>
21,7,What<img src="imgs/>lolz.png" alt = "<heh"/>,<img src="imgs/>lolz.png" alt = "<heh"/>
22,7,<b><a href = "#" title = "4 > 3">hi</a></b>,<b>,<a href = "#" title = "4 > 3">,</a>,</b>
23,10,<StYle><b title = "not in html"></style><B>HTML!</b><style></style>,<StYle>,</style>,<B>,</b>,<style></style>
24,10,<script>//<script>< /script></script><script></script><p>,<script>,</script>,<script>,</script>,<p>
25,10,<i></i this="will be removed by a browser">,<i>,</i this="will be removed by a browser">
26,10,<div id="hi" class=class="what" data-the="heck='is'this" get-good>Attributes are weird<div>,<div id="hi" class=class="what" data-the="heck='is'this">,<div>
27,10,<!--<b>Do you like comments??</b>--><p>,<p>
28,13,<textarea><script>/* *////*///*<!--</script><b>WHAT</b></textarea><i>Hi-->,<textarea>,</textarea>,<i>
29,15,<!--<b>Do you like comments??</b><script>--><script>//<!--hello</script><b>hi</b><!--What--><script>//<!-- <script> <!-- <script> --> </script><i>hello--><script></script>,<b>,</b>,<script>,</script>,<i>,<script>,</script>
30,15,<hi>hi</hi><0>hi</0><h0>hi</h0><h&>hi</h&><&>hi</&><??>hi</??><?php>hi</?php><php?>hi</php?><->hi</-><_-_>hi</_-_><h->hi</h-><_>hi</_><h-_>hi</h-_><?>hi</?><{>hi</{><h{>hi</h{></>hi<//><h~!@#$%^&*()>hi</h~!@#$%^&*()><h>hi</h><h~>hi</h~><h!>hi</h!><@>hi</@><h@>hi</h@><h!@#$%^&*()>hi</h!@#$%^&*()><@f>hi</@f><%>hi</%><;>hi</;><h>>hi</h>><h&>hi</h&><h~>hi</h~>,<hi>,</hi>,<h0>,</h0>,<H&>,</H&>,<PHP?>,</PHP?>,<h->,</h->,<H-_>,</H-_>,<H{>,</H{>,<H~!@#$%^&*()>,</H~!@#$%^&*()>,<H>,</H>,<H~>,</H~>,<H!>,</H!>,<h@>,</h@>,<h!@#$%^&*()>,</h!@#$%^&*()>,<H>,</H>,<H&>,</H&>,<h~>,</h~>
31,30,<hi>hi</hi><0 WHAT_is=HtMl>hi&<i attrubute="oops'></0><h0 attRiBu350Te="<b>oops</b><style>/*">hi</h0>*/<h&>hi</h&><&>hi</&><??>hi</??><?php>hi</?php><php?>hi</php?><->hi</-><_-_>hi</_-_><h->hi</h-><_>hi</_><h-_>hi</h-_><?>hi</?><{>hi</{><h{>hi</h{></>hi&<//><script>     &/*<h~!@#$%^&*()>*/</ script></StyLe>/*</ScrIPT>/*<b>oops</b>hi</h~!@#$%^&*()><h>hi</h><h~>hi</h~><h!>hi</h!><@>hi</@><h@>hi</h@><h!@#$%^&*()>hi</h!@#$%^&*()><@f>hi</@f><%>hi</%><;>hi</;><h>>hi</h>><h&>hi&</h&><h~>hi/*/</h~><b>oops</b>hi</h~!@#$%^&*()><h>hi</h><h~>hi</h~><h!>hi</h!><@>hi</@><h@>hi</h@><h!@#$%^&*()>hi</h!@#$%^&*()><@f>hi</@f><%>hi</%><;>hi</;><h>>hi</h>><h&>hi&</h&><h~>hi/<script></StyLe></ScrIPT><textarea><b>HE COMES</b></textarea><h!>hi</h!><@>hi</@><h@>hi</h@><h!@#$%^&*()>hi</h!@#$%^&*()><@f>hi</@f><%>hi</%><;>hi</;><h>>hi</h>><h&>hi&</h&><h~>hi</h~>,<hi>,</hi>,<i attrubute="oops'></0><h0 attRiBu350Te="<b>,<style>,</style>,<textarea>,</textarea>,<h!>,</h!>,<h@>,</h@>,<h!@#$%^&*()>,</h!@#$%^&*()>,<h&>,</h&>,<h~></h~>
```

Each line is a separate test case. They are in this format:

```
1,1,<b>HTML!</b>,<b>,</b>
| | |            |   |
| | |            +---+- The correct output: all HTML tags in the string separated by commas
| | +- The HTML for you to parse
| +- The number of points you get if you parse this HTML correctly
+- The test case number
```

## Example

Let's say we have the regex [`/<.*?>/g`](https://output.jsbin.com/bagaxepove#%3C.*%3F%3E) (all flavors). For test case #1, it matches 2 times: `<b>`, and `</b>`. The correct output in the test case says that it should match `<b>` and `</b>`, so it is correct. Our regex gets 1 point.

Then for test case #2. Our regex matches `<i>`, `<b>`, `</b>`, and `</i>`,  which is consistent with the test case so we get 1 point.

Now for test case #3. Our regex matches `< b implies b >`, when it should have not matched anything. We get 0 points for that.

Continuing for each test case gets us a score of 50 (out of 207, or 24.15%). Not great. Can you do better?

## Try It Online

If your regex will work with the ECMAScipt / JS flavor than you can try it [here](http://output.jsbin.com/wacebab) and get automatic scoring!

## Tie breaker

Here are the scoring systems. Whoever has the best score on the first wins. In the event of a tie, whoever out of the ties scores the best wins, etc.

1. Most points
2. Shortest length
3. First posted

## Answer format

> ## [insert score here] / 207 points
>
> ```
> [insert regex here]
> ```
>
> Explanation (optional but encouraged)
>
> Proof of score (matched output vs. test cases, link to TIO to try it,
>   etc.)

---

## Meta

- Dupe? ([I don't think so](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bregular-expression%5D+html))

Comment: Any tie breaking for regexes with the same score, e.g. length?

Comment: 1. This is a meta-regex question, and scoring it just on test cases means that there are already programs out there which will generate a regex that gets a perfect score. As it stands it's a pretty pointless contest. 2. I don't see a specification for an HTML tag, or even a link to one. Why, for example, is `< b implies b >` invalid? Without a spec it's even more a meta-regex question rather than an HTML question. 3. This isn't parsing HTML with regex. It's closer to lexing HTML with regex, and no-one said that *that* was impossible or would summon the Elder Ones.

Answer (score 0):

## Collectables, Inc  [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

You're an aspiring collector.  **You want to be the top collector for as many collections as possible**.

Here's how you play (with `P` players):

- The game consists of multiple Auctions, and `2P` collections.  **Some collections are bigger than others**.  Smaller collections are more valuable and rare, bigger collections are cheaper.
- Each Auction puts `2P` random items up for sale
- You place a bid on each item, grouped by collection.  (e.g. If doll was a collection, you place a single bid for all of the dolls in the current Auction)
- You win by having the most pieces for the most collections.  (Each collection is worth 1 point.  If you have the plurality of that collection, you gain that point).

#### Fine Details:

- Players start with 30 gold.
- Each collection contains a different number of items, from `2` to `2P+1`.
- There are `2P+3` auctions (until all items are sold)
- Players can bid on multiple items, and their total bid can exceed their current gold.
- Resolution of bids happens as follows:

  1. All invalid bids are removed.  (Players without enough gold, or bids on items already sold).
  2. Find the top bid (by gold).  Tiebreaker is the collection size (smallest first).
  3. If there is still a tie, then that item group is removed.
  4. Otherwise, the top bidder wins the item group.  His money is added to the pot.
- After an Auction is finished, the pot is evenly distributed among all players.  Any remainder is put back into the pot.

I think that my rules are pretty complete.

- Is it clear?
- Is it interesting?
- How many reads did it take you to understand the post?

Comment: 1. It took me until the third read-through to understand that the collections are split into items and then recombined, possibly because I'm unconsciously applying real-world knowledge about how these things normally work. Explicitly saying that there are `P*2+3` auctions would be a useful hint. 2. I was going to say that point 3 was missing a tie-breaker until I realised that the second sort criterion is collection size and not group size. 3. I think there's some interesting game theory here: things like weighting bids towards odd sized collections vs even sized collections.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks for the feedback!  I added an overview, does that help?

Comment: Best to ask someone who hadn't previously read the question. BTW I presume you're planning to add something later about the I/O?

Comment: Yep.  There isn't any hidden information (unless you count simultaneous as hidden), so the API should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

## Matrix Decomposition

[matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Meta

- Duplicate?
- What rules should I add?
- Are my explanations sufficient?
- Any room for improvement?

It's possible to "factor" any invertible (a.k.a. non-singular) square matrix `A` into a combination of a permutation matrix<sup>1</sup> (`P`), a unit<sup>3</sup> lower triangular matrix<sup>2</sup> (`L`), a diagonal matrix<sup>4</sup> (`D`), and a unit upper triangular matrix<sup>2</sup> (`U`).

That is, `A = PLDU`

For instance, the matrix `[[4, 5], [2, 3]]` can be expressed as the multiplication of the following matrices:

```
P = [[0, 1],
     [1, 0]]
L = [[1, 0],
     [2, 1]]
D = [[2, 0 ],
     [0, -1]]
U = [[1, 3/2],
     [0, 1  ]]
```

## Task

Given an invertible square matrix `A`, output `P`, `L`, `D`, and `U`.

## Test Cases

```
TBD
```

## Rules

- Any reasonable output format is acceptable, but `P`, `L`, `D`, and `U` must be separate outputs.

---

<sup>1. A permutation matrix is a permutation of the identity matrix.</sup>

<sup>2. An upper triangular matrix is a square matrix whose nonzero values occur only on or above the main diagonal, and a lower triangular matrix is a matrix whose nonzero values occur only on or below the main diagonal.</sup>

<sup>3. A unit triangular matrix is a triangular matrix whose main diagonal is all 1s.</sup>

<sup>4. A diagonal matrix is a matrix whose nonzero values occur only on the main diagonal.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Become a Word-Pontif

The french used to define the word `pontif` as `one who builds bridges` stemming from the conjunction of `pons, facere` which literally translates to `a bridge, to create one`. Your task will be, given a list of **1 or more** lower-case words `l (String Array)`, output the **MAXIMUM** length of a bridge that can be built from these words.

---

## Bridge Rules

- Bridges can be made by connecting two or more words together:

  - Words must be connected prefix-to-suffix or suffix-to-prefix.

    - To join two words into one:

      - The suffix of the first must match the prefix of the second (`abc+cba=abcba`).
      - The prefix of the first must match the suffix of the second (`earl+toe=toearl`).
  - If a word's prefix/suffix contains more than one common character:

    - You can only connect them with the maximal common substring.
    - In other words,`abc` and `bcdefg` can be connected using `a[bc]defg`.
- The length of a bridge is simply the length of the conjoined words in characters.

---

## Building Material Rules

- The list will contain at fewest 1 word.
- The list may hold 0 links between words, in this case the maximal size is the longest word in the list.
- The list will not contain the empty string and will only use the lowercase alphabet (`a-z`).
- The list MAY NOT contain duplicates.

---

## Examples

**Example 1:**

```
[abcdefgh,holographic,graphical,quine,loitering]

abcdefholo[graphic]al = 19

19
```

**Example 2:**

```
[noon,moon,loon,noon,groom]

groo[m]oon

8
```

**Example 3:**

```
[spoon,whatifgodwereoneofus,oneofusisatraitor,aaaaaaaaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaaa]

whatifgodwere[oneofus]isatraitor (because the two aaaaa's overlap too much).

30
```

**Example 4:**

```
[abc,def,ghi,jkl,mnop,qrst,uvwxyz]

uvwxyz (No matches)

6
```

**Example 5:**

```
[xox,xxox,lol,lolol,lololol,xoxx]

xo[xx]o[x]ox    < 8  (Maximal of the xox path)
[lol]o[l]ololol < 10 (Maximal of the lol path)

10
```

**Example 6 (Base):**

```
[hi]

hi

2
```

**Example 7:**

```
# Note, when a link has been used it cannot be used twice.
# In other words, the brackets used cannot overlap in these examples.
[aa,aaa,aaaa] 

aa[aa][a]a (Chose to use aaaa,aaa,aa)

7
```

---

## General Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: 1. This is extremely close to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132561/194 . 2. Examples 5 and 7 look wrong.

Comment: In example 1, isn't it `abcdefgholographicaloitering = 28`?

Answer (score 0):

## Validating Words in Word Grids

A follow on from [Generating Word Grids](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/142531/9365)

Given a grid of letters, a set of co-ordinates and a dictionary of words, validate that the co-ordinates follow only cardinal direction changes, at least one of the co-ordinates touch an empty space in the centre of the grid, the resulting word is valid given the dictionary (taking into consideration any blank tiles) and return either the grid, with the letters at the co-ordinates removed along with the score of the word, or, if one of the conditions fail, the original grid and a score of `-1`.

### Details

Please detail the format you want to accept coordinates in any reasonable format is acceptable.

### Scoring

Letters are worth their values as per Scrabble:

```
0 points: blank tiles
1 point: E, A, I, O, N, R, T, L, S, U
2 points: D, G
3 points: B, C, M, P
4 points: F, H, V, W, Y
5 points: K
8 points: J, X
10 points: Q, Z
```

Bonus tiles (indicated by a lowercase letter, or `!` for a blank tile) provide a `*2` multiplier and stack (eg. if my co-ordinates spell `gOLf` I would earn `(((2+1+1+4)*2)*2)`, `32` points).

#### Examples:

Input:

```
6,4 6,5 5,5 4,5 3,5 3,6 2,6 1,6
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaDEdI
TERMDYTSR
ROANJLEFT
EkCI OOsT
IPAJPGMNY
MZLORITVI
GwEGgPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

Output:

```
9
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaD dI
TERMDY SR
ROANJ  FT
EkCI  OsT
IPAJP MNY
MZLO  TVI
GwEGgPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

(spells `RIGOLETE`, `(1+1+2+1+1+1+1)`)

Input:

```
0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaD dI
TERMDY SR
ROANJ  FT
EkCI  OsT
IP  P MNY
MZL   TVI
GwE gPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

Output:

```
-1
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaD dI
TERMDY SR
ROANJ  FT
EkCI  OsT
IP  P MNY
MZL   TVI
GwE gPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

(spells `DEST` which doesn't appear in the dictionary)

Input:

```
5,6 4,6 4,7 4,8
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaD dI
TERMDY SR
ROANJ  FT
EkCI  OsT
IP  P MNY
MZL   TVI
GwE gPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

Output:

```
12
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaD dI
TERMDY SR
ROANJ  FT
EkCI     
IP  P  NY
MZL   TVI
GwE gPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

(spells `MOsT`, `(3+1+1+1)*2`)

### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

- The order is not important, it can be `score` then `grid`, or vice versa.
- Any reasonable format can be used for I/O assuming it is consistent.
- All [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

### Questions for meta

Things have changed a lot in the time since I originally posted this, so rather than just posting I thought I'd bump for fredback.

- What would the best way of using an associated dictionary be, taking it as input?
- Obviously the input format for co-ordinates can be more flexible (0-based index, 1-based index, or something) is mentioning this enough?
- Grid input format can be flexible too, mentioning this should be enough too?
- Any other relevant tags?

Comment: This looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, I'll bear that in mind, i'm not sure how much interest there is based off of part 1, but I might still post this in the next week or so :)

Answer (score 0):

## Word Grid Pathfinding

A follow up to [Generating Word Grids](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/142531/9365) and Validating Words in Word Grids.

---

### Meta

My original idea for this was to have entries compete, but I'd like to have different winning conditions. Given grid `x`, pit all scripts against each other for the following win criteria:

- Highest Score
- Shortest Path
- Fewest remaining tiles
- Longest Words

but I think perhaps just making it code golf and offering a bounty to each of the criteria above after some time. I'd like some feedback on this. I like [@LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33208/legionmammal978)'s idea, but feel like perhaps that could be a separate challenge (again, only if these are interesting to anyone!)

---

Given a grid of letters, complete a path of words that reaches from the centre of the board, to the edges. You must return lists of your moves as co-ordinates and your score will be tallied. As soon as there is a clear path from the centre to the edge, the game is over, and no further words will be scored.

### Details

Grids will always have an equal, odd, number of rows and columns, such that no direction contains fewer tiles.

### Restrictions

In the event that the grid is unsolvable (or becomes unasolvable because of your chosen path, you may return something falsy instead of a list of co-ordinates.

Your script must be able to handle grids of varying sizes and solve them in a reasonable time, such that a service like TIO can be used, without causing problems in most cases, for extremely large inputs (> 500). You are free to take input in any reasonable format, but please include a link to your script with a wrapper such that it can take input in via STDIN/script arguments via an online service.

#TODO: copy details of the adjacency rules from above.

For example, in the grid provided below, the `J`, `I`, `P` or `O` letters (north, east, south and west of the blank square) must be included, once this word has been removed, you have more available words.

There are bonus letters that provide a double point score, denoted by a lowercase letter or `!` (instead of `?` for a blank tile). Blank tiles are used exactly as they are in Scrabble and can count as any letter, the validating program will search for words replacing the `?` (or `!`) with a wildcard. Letters are scored as per Scrabble:

```
0 points: blank tiles
1 point: E, A, I, O, N, R, T, L, S, U
2 points: D, G
3 points: B, C, M, P
4 points: F, H, V, W, Y
5 points: K
8 points: J, X
10 points: Q, Z
```

Your score will be calculated by the validator.

### Examples

Input:

```
UWDESTKP?
ItDBaDEdI
TERMDYTSR
ROANJLEFT
EkCI OOsT
IPAJPGMNY
MZLORITVI
GwEGgPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

Output:

```
6,4 6,5 5,5 4,5 3,5 3,6 2,6 1,6
5,6 4,6 4,7 4,8
```

Total moves: 2
Points: 21

#TODO: more examples.

Answer (score 0):

## Shift-left golfer

Sometimes when doing code-golf, a person needs to understand which format is shorter:

- `2147483648`
- `0x80000000`
- `1<<31`

The task:

You will receive a number in one of the three formats above: decimal, hexadecimal, or shift-left operation. If there is no advantage in converting it to another format, just leave the number the way it is; otherwise I want the shortest format. Of course there are numbers you can't convert to shift-left format!

## Notation:

- **Hexadecimal** — `0x#######....` where there are no leading zeros after the `x`. When accounting for evaluating the golfiness, the `0x` part is also taken into consideration. For example `0x80000000` has a length of 10.
- **Decimal** — `#######....` where there are no leading zeros.
- **Shift-left** — `#...<<#....` no leading zeros both sides of `<<`. The `<<` operator is also considered for length, e.g `1<<31` has a length of 5. You must also handle multiple digits before the `<<` signal.

# represents a digit and ... represent possible repetition of digits

I don't care if you handle leading zeros at the input or not; but if you handle them, you must do the comparison operations without them and output also without them — You're a golfer, come on! You will understand!

There will be no accepted answer.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so I want to know shortest answer by language.

## UPDATE 1:

In spite of @dzaima 's comment, now it also needs to handle multiple digits before `<<` signal.

Comment: How about just take an integer as input and return the shortest form as output?

Comment: `1<<31 has a length of 4` not 5?

Comment: @Riker: Sorry, my mistake. Now fixed.

Comment: @dzaima: Updated. Yes, it will need to handle multiple digits before `<<`

Comment: If you allow non-ones in front of the byte shift as input, but not as output, an input like `99<<99` would result in the output having more bytes than the input.

Comment: What about something like `0x45<<0x378`? i.e., why not hex numbers in left-shifts?

Answer (score 0):

## Translate Tetris moves to GoL!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Unless you've been living under a rock, you're probably aware of the fact that the highest voted unanswered, incredibly hard challenge to [build a working game of Tetris in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11880/68615) just recently got answered. (Go check it out if you haven't already.)

Unfortunately, since this game is written in Conway's Game of Life, giving input to the code is a bit tricky. (Of course, if they can simulate Tetris in GoL, you can play it with tricky moves. :P) To quote the [main answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142673/68615):

> Each move only requires editing a single bit of RAM, and this input register is automatically cleared after the input event has been read.

Each Tetris move corresponds to a single number by the following table:

```
value     motion

1         counterclockwise rotation
2         left
4         down (soft drop)
8         right
16        clockwise rotation
```

Now, of course, if there was only a way to automate this...

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes a **series of keypresses** as input and outputs **each keypress' respective number** according to the table above.

The keypresses should map as the following:

```
value            motion

<                counterclockwise rotation
<left arrow>     left
<down arrow>     down (soft drop)
<right arrow>    right
>                clockwise rotation
```

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/68615) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that perform this task are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged. (Pshh, how likely is that?)
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

```
// incoming
```

---

## Sandbox

- Should I switch from keypresses to strings of `( < v > )`?
- I'm really lacking on tags...
- Bump!

Comment: Not all languages can support keypresses, so using a string would be better.

Comment: Also, if you go for keypresses: What happens if I hold a key for 10s? What happens if I hold a key and simultaneously press another one?

Answer (score 0):

## Two-Symbol n-state Universal Turing Machine

A program is defined as a set of transition rules from one state to another based on the current state and symbol, optionally moving the tape head left or right.

The goal is to produce a program that satisfies all of the following criteria:

- It is a two-symbol Turing Machine program.
- It emulates a two-symbol Turing Machine program that is represented on the tape.
- where all tape that is not data is initialised to one symbol (designated `0` - the other is `1`).

There are two scoring criteria:

1. The number of states. Smaller is better.
2. The compressibility of the program format (see below).

There is an individual scoring for each criterion and a combined position. The combined position is the sum of the ordinal positions in the leaderboard for each criterion (e.g. if your solution is 1st for number of states but 4th for compressibility it has a combined position of 5th). In the likely event of a tie, the compressibility of the program format is the tie-breaker.

### Compressibility of the Program Format

The compressibility of the program format is defined as the number of (additional) states required to write the program onto a blank (`0`) tape, move the head to the start position of the program and start running the emulator on the program (change state to a correct emulator state). *Sandbox note: Hand-compressed test-cases? Average-case Big O?*

Comment: Todo: Work in a reference to [this article](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725) and how a good solution to this challenge will reduce the upper bound for the maximum computable value of the Busy Beaver function.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the Kolmogorov complexity when compressed through a certain method? It seems like the compressibility of the input format is poorly defined and will vary between inputs.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing the busy beaver connection. Clearly it's not about emulating a single program, because in general the program itself would have fewer states than the program which puts it onto the tape and then runs the emulator; so it must be about some kind of loop over all programs, but then you run into undecidability of the termination of the emulator programs, meaning that the emulator certainly doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 0):

## Output an Anagram! No Not That One!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [anagram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given a list of unique strings that are anagrams of each other, output an anagram of those words that is different from each word in the list.

The strings will be alphanumeric, and there is guaranteed to be a valid anagram.

The program or function can, but doesn't have to be non-deterministic, meaning given the same input, multiple running a of the code can yield different outputs, as long as every possible output is a valid one.

#### Test Cases

```
[Input] -> Possible output
-----------------
[ab] -> ba
[aba, aab] -> baa
[123, 132, 231, 312, 321] -> 213
[hq999, 9h9q9, 9qh99] -> 999hq
[abcde123, ab3e1cd2, 321edbac, bcda1e23] -> ba213ecd
```

### Sandbox questions

- Is this a duplicate of anything?
- Any other test cases I should include?

Comment: I should probably post my other sandboxed challenge at some point...

Comment: Should it output the same string each time given the same array of strings as input?

Comment: What do you mean by "*unique*" in the first sentence?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Did that clear it up?

Answer (score 0):

## It’s raining numbers! Better to get a good umbrella!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Your task is to take in one integer input and print a “raining” alternating pattern with that number, and an umbrella of appropriate size to protect yourself from such a rain!

## Examples

```
1 =>

  1
 _|_
/   \
-----
  |
  C


2 =>

  2  
      2
 ___|___
/       \
---------
    |
    |
    C


3 =>

  3       3
      3  
  3       3
 _____|_____
/           \
-------------
      |
      |
      | 
      C


4 =>

  4       4
      4       4
  4       4
      4       4       
 _______|_______
/               \
-----------------
        |
        |
        |
        |
        C


10 =>

  1       1       1       1       1
  0       0       0       0       0
      1       1       1       1       1
      0       0       0       0       0
  1       1       1       1       1
  0       0       0       0       0
      1       1       1       1       1
      0       0       0       0       0
  1       1       1       1       1
  0       0       0       0       0
      1       1       1       1       1
      0       0       0       0       0
  1       1       1       1       1
  0       0       0       0       0
      1       1       1       1       1
      0       0       0       0       0
  1       1       1       1       1
  0       0       0       0       0
      1       1       1       1       1
      0       0       0       0       0    
 ___________________|___________________
/                                       \
-----------------------------------------
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    C
```

## Rules

- The output should use only the ascii characters `_ | - / \ C`, space, and the digits (no tabs are allowed).
- Numbers should have an alternating pattern, two digits on the same line are separated by 7 spaces.
- Number with more than one digit must be written vertically.
- The size of the first line of the top of the umbrella should be equal to 4n-1, for input n, centered below the “rain”; the size of the second line should be equal to 4n+1.
- The shank of the umbrella under the top is centered and should be of height n (the `|` characters), and terminated by a `C` handle.
- Lines can have trailing spaces.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) task, so the shortest solution is any language wins.

Comment: *shorte**st** solution i**n** any*

Comment: I think that you should explicitly state the input for each example output.

Comment: Allowed whitespace should be mentioned in the first rule. Regular spaces seem obvious, but using tab characters in place of 4 spaces could be used and it's a good idea to explicitly allow or forbid it. Also, that rule should start with "The output should..." to clarify that this is not [tag:restricted-source]

Answer (score 0):

## Output the Yggdrasil graph

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

In Norse mythology, [Yggdrasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil), or the world tree, is a giant tree that spans the entire universe and connects all nine worlds of the Norse mythology together. Here, we shall take a rather liberal reinterpretation of the term "world tree" - it's the tree that *contains* all other trees as subgraphs. Not only that, but each graph is present everywhere in Yggdrasil. Clearly, the only way to achieve that is if every node in the graph has infinitely many neighbors.

Yggdrasil is the unique (up to isomorphism) non-empty graph with the two properties that each vertex has ℵ₀ neighbors and that there is a unique simple path between any two vertices. In other words, Yggdrasil is the [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of the free group with countably infinitely many generators. Your goal is to output this graph.

Nodes can be given any printable label of your choice, as long as they are non-empty and unique within the graph. Edges shall be denoted as pairs of vertices in either order. It must be clear from the output which are the two nodes in a graph (`a-b-c` is not an acceptable representation of an edge from `a-b` to `c`, but `["a-b", "c"]` is fine). In the output, each edge shall be output on a single line, and different edges shall go on different lines.

The output should be just the list of edges in the graph, one edge per line. Each edge in the graph must be output exactly once, and in a finite amount of time (barring memory limitations). Edges not in the graph must not be output. For example:

- Listing the edges in breath-first order is not sufficient, as any edge disjoint from the root would not get output.
- Listing the edges in depth-first order is not sufficient, as no more than two edges of any node would ever get output.
- It is sufficient (but not necessarily optimal) to generate the output by repeating (for each node in a copy of the list of known nodes, take the first unknown child, output the edge to it and add it to the list of known nodes).

The sufficient example above will output, if nodes are labeled `0`, `0 1`, `0 2`, `0 1 1`, ... :

```
0 => 0 1
0 => 0 2
0 1 => 0 1 1
0 => 0 3
0 1 => 0 1 2
0 2 => 0 2 1
0 1 1 => 0 1 1 1
...
```

Comment: So basically we have a countably infinite set of vertices V, a countably infinite index set I, and an injection (V x I) -> V. Since any bijection is an injection, we can use minor variants of e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8892/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78606/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48705/194 with a loop `for(n=0;;n++)` wrapped round to create a valid answer. So although quite well disguised this is actually a dupe.

Comment: @PeterTaylor not sure how that would work. Are you trying to output the complete infinite graph rather than the infinite order regular tree?

Comment: Use the reverse direction of the bijection: N -> (N x N). Then `for(n=0;;n++)print(unpair(n)[0],"=>",n)`. Every node has an infinite number of successors, but each node has only one predecessor, so it's a tree. For the previous questions which use a bijection N -> (Z x Z) it's ever so slightly more subtle: to enumerate the entire tree we need to add in a bijection N -> Z and write `for(n=0;;n++)print(unpair(n)[0],"=>",z(n))`, but there are some very simple bijections N -> Z.

Answer (score 0):

## Sort a nested object by nested value

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your goal is to sort a nested object by a nested value. What does that mean? For example:

**#1: Input**

```
{
    foo: {
        category: "A",
        hello: "world",
        color: "blue"
    },
    bar: {
        category: "B",
        cu: "cumber",
        color: "blue"
    },
    baz: {
        category: "A",
        let: "tuce",
        color: "green",
    }
}
```

**#1a: Output** *sorted by* `category`

```
{
    A: {
        foo: {
            hello: "world",
            color: "blue",
        },
        baz: {
            let: "tuce",
            color: "green"
        }
    },
    B: {
        bar: {
            cu: "cumber",
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

**#1b: Output** *sorted by* `color`

```
{
    blue: {
        foo: {
            hello: "world",
            category: "A"
        },
        bar: {
            cu: "cumber",
            category: "B"
        }
    },
    green: {
        baz: {
            let: "tuce",
            category: "A"
        }
    }
}
```

> Note that the sorting key is always deleted from the objects (when sorting by `color` none of the items contain `color`).

### Your task

Given an object, and a sorting key (a string), output the sorted object as shown.

### Rules

- You can always assume that the value of the sorting key is a string (as it also needs to be a key in the output)
- You can always assume that the given sorting key exists in all values
- Sorting will only occur on the first-level objects, but the sorting key can be nested (see test case #2)
- The object may be a JSON object, a python dict, a JS object, etc. but must always have string only keys.
- You may accept the object as a JSON string and/or return a JSON string.

### Test Cases

**#2: Input**

*Sort by:* `rating.healthiness`

```
{
    icecream: {
        sweet: true,
        rating: {
            tastiness: "8",
            healthiness: "4"
        }
    },
    pizza: {
        sweet: false,
        rating: {
            tastiness: "9",
            healthiness: "3"
        }
    },
    chocolatecake: {
        sweet: true,
        rating: {
            tastiness: "8",
            healthiness: "3"
        }
    }
}
```

**#2: Output** (*sorted by* `rating.healthiness`)

```
{
    "3": {
        pizza: {
            sweet: false,
            rating: {
                tastiness: "9"
            }
        },
        chocolatecake: {
            sweet: true,
            rating: {
                tastiness: "8"
            }
        }

    },
    "4": {
        icecream: {
            sweet: true,
            rating: {
                tastiness: "8"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

---

### Sandbox Questions

1. I really need to make the question clearer. Any thoughts? How can I better describe the task?
2. Is this a duplicate?
3. I'm guessing I need a better title. Any ideas?
4. Should I make the input a JSON object or just a general object?
5. Are multi-level nested objects even possible? Would it be too easy without them?
6. Should I also allow booleans & numbers as the value for the sorting key (and then in a key form it would be stringified)?

Answer (score 0):

## Is my Sukkah Kosher?

> [Do not rely on this text for questions of Jewish law!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)

You will be given a floor plan of a [*sukkah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkah) as follows:

- A rectangular 2D text (in any reasonable format).
- The first and last rows and columns will consist of printable ASCII (32-126).
- All interior characters will be spaces.

Determine if the *sukkah* is acceptible according to these simplified rules, using the scale of one character width/height representing the [*tefach*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Length_and_distance) unit.

- The inner area, as encompassed by the completion of the two longest solid walls into a square, must be at least 6 units by 6 units.
- If the two longest solid walls are across from each other, then the shorter one must be at least 6 units long, and the length with with they are diametrically across from each other must also be 6 units long.
- There must be an additional wall which is at least one unit long.
- The walls may be made of any material, i.e. any character except space.
- Walls with single unit gaps are still considered solid.

You may answer with any two distinct values, but please specify if different from `true`/`1` and `false`/`0`. Explanations are appreciated.

#### Acceptable

```
oOOOo.ooo...o--o   
#              @   
#              )   
#              (   
#                  
|                  
#                  
+++++++*******
```

---

```
oOOOo.ooo...o--o   
                     
                     
                 @   
                 @   
                 @   
                     
   +++++****
```

---

```
o O o o o . o        
                     
                     
                 @

                 @   
                 @   
                     
   +++++****
```

#### Not acceptable

```
oOOOo.ooo...o--o   
#              @   
#              )   
               (   
                   
|                  
#                  
++++      ****
```

---

```
       oOOOo.ooo..
                     
                     
                 @   
                 @   
                 @   
                     
+++++****
```

---

```
o O o o o . o        
                     
                     
                 @

                 @   
                 @   
                 8  
                 8
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Answer (score 0):

### A Conc-urn-ing Problem

You have a mysterious urn, which contains **0 <= n <= 10** sets of **k** balls. Each set of balls shares a numeric label, from zero to **n-1**. You perform a repeated experiment, wherein you remove a ball from the urn, and note its number. If the number of balls in the urn with the same label as the ball you removed has the highest or tied for highest frequency still in the urn, you put the ball back in.

Taking the recorded results of each of the trials yields an infinite sequence. For example, you might have for **n=2, k=2** pulled: **1001000000...**

Given **n** and **k** write a program or function that returns a regular expression which will match any valid real number generated by this process, and which fails to match any other real number.

#### Sandbox

This is missing quite a bit (haven't written a program yet), but I'm not sure if it is too tedious the way that it currently is. It's somewhat boring if restricted to **n=2** but rather quickly becomes tedious after that. Since most of the result would be symmetric, would it make sense to only require the "first" result? This also seems like it removes too much of the interest in the problem.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

## Search Stack Overflow for Duplicates

The Stack Overflow search algorithm has been [under fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357462/5223757) recently. Several problems with the search algorithm being flawed exist, but one of the most important issues raised is with duplicates:

> [...] The search engine is used while authoring a question to find potential duplicates. At that point there is no way for you to take advantage of its features through custom search operators, and it absolutely, positively must be as good as an external search engine in this scenario. Unfortunately, it isn't. – [IInspectable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) [(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357464/5223757#comment520365_357464)

A flawed duplicate search algorithm causes a lot more work for the comparatively few reviewers and duplicate closers than there should be, by not informing the question askers that the question that they are attempting to post is a duplicate. It is also bad for the question askers, preventing them from finding the answer to their question until somebody reviews the question.

This is where you come in. Given the title, body and tags of a question, output a list of 25 relevant questions in a reasonable format (e.g. question ids). Your program should run within 500ms on the Stack Exchange servers for each question. *(Sandbox note: How fast are the Stack Exchange servers? What conversion factor should I use to test on my hardware?)* You have access to all T-SQL database tables available from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), but the current question that needs to be checked for duplicates will be absent from all tables (so it isn't found as a duplicate of itself). To test the algorithm, it would be tested on a random selection of or all of the existing duplicates on Stack Overflow - the algorithm with the lowest average position of the duplicate master(s) in the list would win, where "not in the list" is counted as 50. The set of existing duplicates tested would be the same for all algorithms to test - rationale includes scoring of questions with multiple duplicate masters. The search algorithm should be deterministic. It is allowed to prepare a cache table beforehand - none of the duplicates to test will be passed to this part of the algorithm. This cache table should be able to be updated with new questions without being completely rebuilt. *(Sandbox note: How to score this?)*

*(Sandbox note: The final paragraph should be spread out and better laid out and reworded, but I think the wall of text contains enough information.)*

Answer (score 0):

## Constructively golf *true* primes!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

---

### Introduction

A recurring pattern that I see in challenge involving primes is the (over-) use of prime-checking built-ins and of factorization built-ins. However, I kinda don't trust especially the latter, which is why today, we're gonna *build* primes and include a certificate that the result is actually a prime.

### Input

A positive integer `n` denoting the length of the resultung prime in a basis of your choice.

### Output

A list of primes in the base you picked above, one of these primes is of length `n` and one of these primes is smaller than 20.

### What to do?

Your challenge is to generate a prime of length `n` of which the primality can be reduced to the primality of one of the following primes: `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]`. This can be achieved using [Pocklington's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test#Pocklington_criterion). Now the idea is to chain up from any of these primes using said criterion to a prime of appropriate size, while also outputting the intermediate steps so primality can be checked easily.

For your convenience, I shall reproduce the relevant theorem here:

> Let `N>1` be an integer and suppose there exist `a,q` such that
>
> - `q` is prime
> - `q` divides `N-1`
> - `q>sqrt(N)-1`
> - `a^(N-1) mod N == 1`
> - `gcd(a^((N-1)/q)-1,N)=1`
>
> Then `N` is prime.

And as you might see, your initial set of primes (as candidates for `q`) is limited to the above short list of primes smaller than 20.

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution in bytes wins!
However this is also [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) so all solutions must run in (expected) polynomial time in `n`. Standard IO and Loophole rules apply.

### Got any help?

If you need algorithmic help, I suggest you consult the *[Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)*, chapter 4 ([PDF](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf)), algorithm 4.62 (on page 153 or 22 in the PDF) or you independently look for *Maurer's prime generation algorithm* (originally published [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00202269)).

Answer (score 0):

## I got them Mad Matrix Moves

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

---

Given a list of edges representing a simple directed graph and (optionally) the number of vertices `n>1`, output the [**adjacency matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of that graph.

The vertices will always be numbered **consecutively** starting at `0` (or `1` -- your choice).

The adjacency matrix is defined as the `n` by `n` square matrix `M` such that `M[i][j]` is `1` if there is an edge from vertex `i` to vertex `j` and `0` otherwise.

## Example

For this example and the test cases, we will have the vertices numbered starting at `1`.

Let's use the sample input `[(1,2),(1,3),(3,2)]`. Since there are vertices numbered `1-3`, `n=3` and our output is a `3 x 3` matrix.

The output should be

```
[[0, 1, 1],    <= (1,1) doesn't exist in the input list, (1,2) does, (1,3) does.
 [0, 0, 0],    <= (2,1) doesn't exist, same with (2,2) and (2,3)
 [0, 1, 0]]    <= (3,1) doesn't exist, (3,2) does, and (3,3) doesn't
```

(concisely represented as `[[0,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]]` in test cases).

## Notes

- Every vertex is the start and/or end of at least one edge.
- You may replace `1` and `0` in the output with any two consistent distinct values of your choosing.
- The input graph is simple, meaning that it has no loops nor multiple edges (e.g. no edge `[1,1]` or graph `[[1,2],[1,2]]`)
- The graph is directed, meaning that each edge has a start and an edge (e.g. the edge `[1,2]` is distinct from `[2,1]`)
- Every vertex is an endpoint of at least one edge
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in byes in each language wins.

## Test Cases

One test case per line. Each test case is in the format `edges, n => output`.

```
[(1,2)], 2 => [[0,1],[0,0]]
[(2,1)], 2 => [[0,0],[1,0]]
[(1,2),(2,1)], 2 => [[0,1],[1,0]]
[(1,2),(1,3),(3,2)], 3 => [[0,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)], 5 => [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]
[(1,2),(3,4),(4,3),(2,1),(2,4),(4,2)], 4 => [[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)], 5 => [[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
[(1,2),(3,1),(2,3),(1,1),(2,1)], 3 => [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,0]]
[(1,2),(3,2),(1,3),(5,4),(5,6),(5,1),(2,3),(1,5),(5,2),(3,6),(4,5),(5,3),(2,1),(3,5),(4,6),(6,3),(6,5),(4,2),(3,4)], 6 => [[0,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Get the Average Number of Bytes for an Answer

Have you ever wanted to know the average number of bytes all the answers to a given code golf question took? Probably not. But I did!

### Input

You'll have to take in a link to a codegolf exchange question by text or you can run this in a browser extension/user-script. If you have a clever way of identifying the webpage and producing the necessary output, just ask about it in the comments, and I'll update the question as long as it doesn't violate the rules. The input will be a link to a codegolf question. It will include http::// or https:://. The slashes will be facing this way: "/". The link may not be to a code-golf challenge specifically, but it could be something like a code-challenge.

### Output

If the user inputs something that isn't to a code golf website output something along the lines of "Hey! That's not a link to a code-golf challenge" If the user inputs a link that links to the codegolf exchange, but isn't a codegolf (maybe it's a code-challenge) the program should output anything that is not a natural number.

If there are strikethroughs through previous amounts of bytes a solution took, those should not be included in the average. If the person answering the question in one of the links did not conform to formatting standards, the program doesn't have to account for it. Minor differences will be allowed. Specifically, the number of bytes should be within 5 lines of the top of the answer and bolded.

All answers should be rounded to the nearest whole number with .5 rounding up.

### Examples

Input:

`https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/average-out-two-lists`

Output:

`95`

### Winning Criterion

The winner will be given by (1 / execution time (s) + bytes).

If you know of anything that I missed, comment below.

Comment: What if I make the output message my entire program and then just `exec` it?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I'm not really sure what that means. If it takes a link in and outputs the answer then you've completed the challenge. If it outputs the answer and 20 lines of unnecessary information that the user can see, I would say that that doesn't pass the program.

Comment: My point is, what if I make a string containing my entire program, use string slicing to output a good falsy message, and then use `exec` to run the string? Would I be exempted from counting the bytes of my string?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino That's a smart way to get around the rules. No, you wouldn't be exempt from the rules, but from a literal interpretation, you could argue that that is allowed. How should most concisely update my rules to prevent this?

Comment: I'd just guarantee that the input will follow a specific format, because making the input contain backslashes, missing components, etc. is just a pain and doesn't demonstrate the answerer's ability to actually do what you really want. Essentially, don't add too much fancy stuff

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Okay, I've updated the question.

Comment: `along the lines of ` → unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Also what _exactly_ is the winning criteria? Another point: A link to this site never have `https:://`, only `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

## **Optimised Hashing**

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

For a given set of input, output a program that can 'hash' the input with a minimum number of collisions.

### **The Challenge**

Write a method or function that receives an array of Strings (see input for more detail) and outputs a full program. This program must, for each String in the original input array, print to STDOUT (or equivalent) some positive integer i where i<100 and is unique for that input.

### **The Input**

Each program will be tested with 4 different input sets of 50 unique Strings;

- 50 English words of the same length.
- 50 English words of differing lengths.
- 50 randomly generated character strings of the same length
- 50 randomly generated character strings of differing lengths

*All* Strings in all inputs will only contain the character set [a-zA-z] (ASCII values 65-90 and 97-122) and will all be no more than 20 characters long.

### **Special Rules**

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Inbuilt hashing functions are not allowed.
- You must provide a free and easily accessible environment to compile and run both programs with your answer.
- I reserve the right to discount any program which takes more than 10 minutes to complete any test.

### **Scoring**

You will be scored by combining the following;

- The byte count of your original program
- The byte count of each outputted program
- 5 penalty points for each 'collision'.

I will keep and update a leader board as programs are added and I can test them.

Please let me know if I've missed anything; this is my first question idea!

Answer (score 0):

## Hunting The Wren

Write a program to produce the words to the folk song *Hunting The Wren*.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80n4CW0dE1A

```
"We're hunting the wren." says Robin to Bobbin.
"We're hunting the wren." says Richard to Robin.
"We're hunting the wren." says Jack of the land.
"We're hunting the wren." says everyone.

"Where oh where?" says Robin to Bobbin.
"Where oh where?" says Richard to Robin.
"Where oh where?" says Jack of the land.
"Where oh where?" says everyone.
```

The song continues with the same structure.

```
"In yonder green bush."
"How get him down?"
"With sticks and stones."
"How get him home?"
"The brewer's big cart."
"How will we eat him?"
"With knives and forks."
"Who'll come to the dinner?"
"The King and the Queen."
```

The song concludes with three more verses, which because they have no repetition, we'll omit for the purposes of this challenge.

**Rules**

- The program must produce the full words of the song as 54 or 55 lines of text.
- Each verse of four lines must be separated by a blank line. A blank line on the end is optional.
- You must not use a text decompression library. (GZIP the whole song is 380 bytes.)
- Normal code golf rules apply. Shortest code wins.

**C# Reference Implementation**

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string[] starts = new [] {
      "We're hunting the wren.",  
      "Where oh where?",            "In yonder green bush.",
      "How get him down?",          "With sticks and stones.",
      "How get him home?",          "The brewer's big cart.",
      "How will we eat him?",       "With knives and forks.",
      "Who'll come to the dinner?", "The King and the Queen." };

    string[] ends = new [] {
      "says Robin to Bobbin.",      "says Richard to Robin.",
      "says Jack of the land.",     "says everyone."            };

    foreach (string start in starts)
    {
      foreach (string end in ends)
      {
        System.Console.WriteLine("\"" + start + "\" " + end);       
      }
      System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is likely to be closed as a dupe, possibly of [Rickroll](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6956/42963), or possibly of [Write lines in detention](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40206/42963).

Answer (score 0):

## Pokémon Champion

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)<sup>*</sup>

This challenge is about writing the ultimate bot for battling Pokémon. Since knowledge of [competitive Pokémon battling](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/competitive-battling-basics-tiering-faq.3545934/) is necessary, I'll leave that to the experts at [Smogon University](http://www.smogon.com/).

#### Rules

- Your bot must battle another bot in a Gen 7 Random Battle Format.
- Your bot will be judged based on its performance in a round-robin tournament orchestrated by the author of the challenge, against all other submitted bots before a specific deadline.
- In order to avoid reinventing the wheel, there are [several frameworks](https://github.com/search?q=pokemon+showdown+bot) already available to choose from. Unfortunately, a lot of these are written in Node.js, so you might still have some porting to do, unless this challenge decides to create its own framework for battling.
- Since your bot will be connecting to a Showdown server using the existing Web Socket API, any error in your program that causes the bot to become non-responsive or to disconnect will automatically forfeit that match.
- Standard loopholes apply, and do not exploit any possible bugs in the API. If you find a bug, please report it [here](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/bug-reports-v2-0-read-op-before-posting.3469932/).

#### Further Considerations

While in theory, I think this would be a great idea, I believe this would require a lot of time-investment and groundwork, which frankly I don't have the availability for right now, so anyone is free to take this over, but please be courteous and get my consent in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) first. Just @PatrickRoberts and wait for a reply before modifying this proposal.

[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)<sup>*</sup> Not sure if it's preferable to write an API specifically for this challenge to eliminate the need for Web Socket communication, since there are already [available platforms](https://github.com/dramamine/leftovers-again). The idea is to host an official tournament at a certain date (yet undecided) on [Pokémon Showdown](http://pokemonshowdown.com/).

Comment: I could use a new bot on my side server (the one I've got doesn't know about Z-moves so even I can beat it at Ultimate Z...)

Answer (score 0):

## All the same digits

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

#### Task

For any two coprime integers `n, b > 1` there exist infinitely many integers `k > 0` for which `n * k`'s representation in base `b` only contains the digit `b-1`.
This challenge's task is to output the smallest such `k` for given integers `n, b`.

#### Input

Two integers `n, b` with the above described properties in any reasonable format (integers, strings, ...). If your language does not support arbitrary precision integers, you can assume that `n, b < 2**31`.

#### Ouput

An integer `k` with the above described properties in any reasonable format (integer, string, ...). If your language does not support arbitrary precision integers, you can assume that `k < 2**31`.

#### Test cases

```
f(  n,     b) == k

f(  7,    10) == 142857
f(  13,    5) == 48
f(  14,   13) == 12
f(1728, 1729) == 1
f( 107,   99) == 54863250648363053681585635237627534906401818527472898624219397466199311510764517134614152141940101983414
```

To generate more test cases, take a look at my [reference implementation](https://tio.run/##VczNCoJAFIbhtXMVH0Tg2EhNm2jAlftuQEScPKKkxziNRZtu3X52rd@X5/oM3cT7ZVnhPPGdJIArjzDhVNmdypFhqEff1GAD73Cbx9gnCSUN2klApkHPIJ5HkjpQzIVzqS21VmqFG9Vy7n7jRTXUoo2/ioFkVjsVPbp@IORx8Up9mYjxes1ONplVkVCYhf/alper9Bw@it0dDI5HvbwB) written in Python 2.

#### Addendum

Fraction periods can also be used to calculate `k` (example given for `n, b = 13, 10`).

```
1/13             =      0.076923(076923)* (period length 6)
1/13 *  10**6    = 076923.076923(076923)*
1/13 * (10**6-1) = 076923
        999999   = 076923 * 13
               k =  76923
```

Comment: Not true. Consider `n=b>1`. You need a coprimality condition.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 0):

## Behavior Driven Golfing

#### Context

From wikipedia (emphasis mine): [Behavior Driven Development (BDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) is largely facilitated through the use of a simple domain-specific language (DSL) using **natural language constructs (e.g., English-like sentences)** that can express the behavior and the expected outcomes.

Example in normal BDD (also from Wikipedia):

> Story: Returns go to stock
>
> As a store owner
> In order to keep track of stock
> I want to add items back to stock when they're returned.

#### The challenge:

Write a program that reads like a single **English-like sentence** that executes the meaning of that sentence.

#### Other details

- The program must receive input of some kind (stdin, arguments are okay depending on your language's syntax).
- The input can be limited in scope, (e.g. all real numbers, all positive even integers), but there must be infinitely many possible inputs assuming that your language doesn't have a cap.

  - For example, if the input is an integer, you don't actually have to handle integers beyond the language's cap, if your language happens to cap at 32 bit long, it just has to be infinitely many in theory but not necessarily in practice.
- The program must have at least `log(n)` distinct outputs over an input space of size `n`.

  - For example, if there existed a language where `convert to zero` was a valid program, returning `0` on all inputs would not be okay, but printing a number of `0` equal to the base 10 number of digits of the input number would be okay.
- The program should not error out on legal input.
- Irregular case and unicode characters are allowed
- Unicode characters will be interpreted as the similar character in English (so most commands in [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) are allowed).
- Words may be delimited by punctuation marks instead of spaces, but they must be delimited.
- Punctuation should not be present in the middle of a word unless it's legal in English (such as an apostrophe in a contraction or a possessive)

Example valid answer for all requirements except the "must take input" requirement:

> #### HQ9+
>
> Print Hello, world.

Since only the H character is an instruction in this language, all the other characters are ignored, and the program prints `hello, world`. Since case is ignored, this program does what the english sentence says it will do.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: As it's currently written, the task is way too broad. The task that the program should do must be narrowed and clearly specified (e.g., "add the input with itself") in order for this to be well-received.

Comment: I like the challenge, but I think it should be [tag:popularity-contest] rather than code-golf. I just feel like code-golf will attract too many answers similar to the example: pick a language that ignores most characters, then write a sentence that describes a built-in and includes that built-in as the only executed character. Popularity Contest seems like it would attract much more interesting answers.

Comment: @KamilDrakari popularity-content is typically not well received, most of those are closed.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how we can measure "X is a *similar character* to Y" objectively.. Probably @Kamil is right and this should be a popularity contest.

Comment: @BruceForte, pop-con is **not** a "solution" to the problem that the spec is not objective. A pop-con should have an objective validity criterion and not be amenable to an objective scoring criterion.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm posting this on sandbox first, because this might not be a good challenge for this site, or just too complicated, because it's about constructing a meaningful sentence. Please, tell me, if it's appropriate task for this site.**

*Also a note: If you want, I can wait for Christmas with this.*

## Back to the *New Year*!

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

*You encounter a probably hard challenge.*

Inspired by [this answer by @dansalmo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17103/).

If we sum character codes in the string `Happy new year to you!`, we will get 2014. With later years, people started to modify the string, so it fits the current year:

- 2015: `A Happy New Year to You!`
- 2016: `Happy New Year to you!!!`

### The challenge

Given an integer *`year`*, output a string meaning "Happy new year!". Sum of character codes should be equal to the integer.

Rules:

- No [default loop holes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) allowed
- Output rules:

  - Meaning rules:

    - You must use the word `Happy` - you cannot use any other adjective instead.
    - You must wish a NEW year, no matter if it's 2010 or 2020!
    - You can only wish a happy new **year** - You can't wish a happy new Easter...
    - You can target the string to a person or group, or to everybody: `Happy new year!`, `Happy new year, Soaku!`, `Happy new year, CodeGolfers!`
    - You can add new words, but the sentence can't lose the meaning!
    - Output must have valid grammar, but you can mess up the punctuation. Just note that you can't use punctuation characters except trailing exclamation marks.
  - Letter case rules:

    - First word must start with uppercase letter.
    - Any other word can start with uppercase or lowercase.
    - Letters that aren't first should be lowercase. The only exception is when all letters in the word are uppercase.
  - Punctuation rules:

    - You are not allowed to use any punctuation characters, except on the end of the string
    - There must be exactly **one** or **three** exclamation marks `!` at the end.
  - Spacing rules:

    - There must be exactly **one** space between words.
    - **No line breaks allowed**
    - Leading and trailing spaces/newlines are allowed, but they don't count in the character code sum. `Word` is the same as outputting `Word`.
  - Character rules:

    - You cannot use digits!
    - You must only use ASCII letters (the only exception are the trailing exclamation marks)
- You can assume the input is an integer between 2000 and 3000

### Test cases

*examples, don't need to be the same*

```
2001 - Happy new YEAR to MYSELF!
2002 - A VERY HAPPY NEW YEAR TO PPCG!
2003 - Happy NEW Year TO MYSELF!!!
2004 - A happy new year to me!
2013 - A HAPPY NEW Year To The SE!!!
2014 - Happy new year to you!
2015 - A Happy New Year to You!
2016 - Happy New Year to you!!!
2030 - A Happy New Year To PPCG!!!
```

---

**Please, suggest any changes and upgrades in the comments**

Comment: I think `meaning "Happy new year!"` is too unclear.  There is no way to objectively enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

## Are these numbers perfect for each other?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

A *perfect number* is a **number that is the sum of its divisors**. Examples of perfect numbers are:

```
     | Divisors                                  | Divisor sum
-----+-------------------------------------------+-------------
6    | 1, 2, 3                                   | 6
28   | 1, 2, 4, 7, 14                            | 28
496  | 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248          | 496
```

Similarly, numbers that are perfect for each other are numbers where **each is the sum of the other's divisors**.

```
     | Divisors                                  | Divisor sum
-----+-------------------------------------------+-------------
220  | 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55, 110   | 284
284  | 1, 2, 4, 71, 142                          | 220
```

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes **two positive integers** and outputs a truthy/falsey value based on **whether they are perfect for each other**.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- The output **must be consistent** for both truthy and falsey values.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that perform this task are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

### Test cases

```
Input         Output

1, 1          truthy
3, 7          falsey
6, 6          truthy
13, 42        falsey
220, 284      truthy
563, 492      truthy
1184, 1210    truthy
```

In a few better formats:

```
1, 1
3, 7
6, 6
13, 42
220, 284
563, 492
1184, 1210

1 1
3 7
6 6
13 42
220 284
563 492
1184 1210
```

### Reference implementation

This is written in [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).

```hs
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors 1 = [1]
divisors n = [i | i <- [1..n - 1], n `mod` i == 0]

perfectPair :: (Integer, Integer) -> Bool
perfectPair (a, b) = (sum $ divisors a) == b && (sum $ divisors b) == a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49b4MwFEV3fsUdosiWDMIOoTQqGbp1qJQdIWGKk1rlS4Z06n@nflUaUXV6V@883@N3PX2Ytl2Wxn7aaXATDge89LO5GIfwiOKWy@B@IJGjkKtFTwuLL1g8hR5FUY8QshSeVN3QVB7kOeIyCEbjzuZtPmnrSMRu7eJXycn5PAztn0umBWruLWy6dtjgbtacimtst/9Q/YP00mlL/@v0@Ao2OtvPiLAq5yiYFJBcgO0EHmimAilNpWIBlSWU96mnyaOiLGWW@CdKxrxcvgE)

[This challenge was sandboxed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14127)

Comment: Although I wouldn't really VTC (seems fine to me), this is very likely to be closed as a dupe of [Am I perfect (number)?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58026/am-i-perfect-number).

Comment: it's also kinda trivial... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8ET/w93//0cbWZjoGBkZxAIA "05AB1E – Try It Online") - 3 bytes, 05AB1E

Answer (score 0):

## Self-language validator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)

Create a language validator, which takes a string/file that might or might not be syntactically in the language of your choice, and returns a value corresponding to whether or not it is a syntactically valid program in the implementing language.

- At a bare minimum, your submission must return a truthy value for code where a strict implementation compiles/interprets without any problems, and must return a falsey value for code that even lax implementations cannot recognise as valid in your language.
- Your submission must have cases where it returns a truthy value, and cases where it returns a falsey value.
- As long as a construct is syntactically valid and could possibly be of the correct scope/type/whatever, it can be called valid. No need to dig into a repository to fetch documentation for an import or anything like that.
- Constructs whose syntactic validity depends on the current runtime execution state do not need to be checked, as statically checking their validity would necessitate reasoning about program execution.
- Appealing to external programs/libraries or to the compiler/interpreter, runtime, or standard libraries to parse or execute the string as language instructions for you would circumvent the whole point of this challenge, and thus is forbidden.
- Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: I don't think [tag:quine] is correct. Also, you might want to be more explicit that there must be a false case, as languages like Seriously are always syntactically valid.

Comment: I wonder how many languages get trivial solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

## Tetris battle

[tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetris) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

---

I guess you know what Tetris is, but if you don't I'll try to explain:

So there is a 2 dimensional board, often with size 10x20. On the top of the board, in the middle, there is a random tetrominoe (also rotated randomly), a figure made of 4 squares. There are 7 shapes:

```
L    J   S    Z    T   O   I

#    #   ##  ##   ###  ##  #
#    #  ##    ##   #   ##  #
##  ##                     #
                           #
```

Every second, the tetrominoe (later called "block") will move 1 cell to the bottom until there is no space left. Player can control it - Move it to left, right, rotate it by 90 degrees (left or right) or speed up its fall. When it can't fall down further, a new block is created and you take the control over it, losing possibility to move the previous block.

**The target is to get as much points as possible. Player can get them, by filling a line (which is then removed)**, for example:

```
        !
        !
        !
****####!$ <- user scores a point, the line is now removed
 &&&&  $$$
```

*different character is a different block*

Player can lose if there is no place for a new block to spawn.

[You can play Tetris online here](http://codeincomplete.com/games/tetris/)

---

### The battle

In this challenge, you will have to create a bot to play Tetris. Unlike a normal playthrough, there will be two players playing on a single board.

Let's call the bots A and B.

#### Block spawning

Every block will start on the left, or right side, depending which bot's it is (left - A, right - B). There will be a 2 block margin, so the block will have some space to rotate. Block will always spawn with left/right align, not centered.

> If a block can't fit, it will try to rotate, so it can be placed. If all 4 directions fail, you die.

Example for 10 width board:

```
--A----B--
```

#### Random size board

**Width**: random even number between 8 and 16.

**Height**: random number between 15 and 25.

It's to make it a bit harder. Try to plan your strategy so it fits all the heights!

### Scoring

You gain 1 point per destroyed block. Some bonus rules apply:

#### Enemy's block isn't my block

You can't use blocks placed by your enemy to gain score. After adding the last block to a line, you gain as much score as much sub-blocks you placed in it. Enemy sub-blocks don't count. Example:

```
Player A filled the line.
AAAABBBAAB
Player A gets 6 points.
Player B doesn't earn any.
```

#### Combos

If you do a move that removes more than just 1 line, you gain x times more score. Of course, x is the amount of lines.

```
Player A filled the line
--ABBB
AAABBBABBB <
BBBBBBABBB <
BBBBAAABBB < 
 B AA ABBB
Player A removed 3 lines.
Player A removed 12 (4+5+3) blocks he owns.
Player A scores 36 points.
```

#### Death & Game Over

When a new fails to spawn, it tries to rotate 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees. If it still can't spawn. You lose. Note it won't try to change it's position, so be careful and try to not put any blocks in the spawn area.

When you die, you can't place any more blocks.

- In case your enemy has more points than you, you lose.
- Otherwise, the game doesn't end yet – the enemy will get double points for the next 10 blocks. The game will end when the bonus ends, when he beats your score or when he dies.

When the game is over, the bot with more points win.

> The game will also end automatically after 300 actions. See API > Actions section for more information.

### Controller

Work in progress. https://github.com/Soaku/Tetris-KOTH

### API

Can't really tell you how it's gonna look like without a controller, right?

However, there is a project of how it's gonna look like:

#### Actions

Every game consists of actions. Your bot function will be executed at the beginning of each action. At the end of each, active tetrominoes will move 1 cell to the bottom.

The controller will wait a configurable amount of time between actions unless the preview is disabled.

Your function should return an integer in at most 0.1 seconds, otherwise your action is terminated and ignored. If it will cross the limit repeatedly, I might remove it.

### Rules

- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Aggressive bots are allowed but discouraged.
- You cannot use any external libraries. The controller uses jQuery, but you aren't allowed to use it.
- Don't try to access the document – Don't write nor read data.
- Don't write your bot to beat specific enemies by countering their strategies.
- Enemy spawn works like an occupied block. You cannot place anything here.

### Main scoring

Every bot will play with every other bot.

Scoring works this way:

- Victory: 2 points
- Tie: 1 point
- Lose: 0 points

Comment: I feel like the last part (bonus round) there probably isn't such a good idea. especially since bots are mostly programmed to play against one enemy, so it means a regular bot needs to implement special cases for one round, which really doesn't add much.

Comment: If you do decide to make a massively multiplayer one, it's sort of unfair to bots that will perform better at the side that end up in the middle or vice versa, so making it a cylinder (the rows wrap around into themselves) would help

Comment: Fine, I removed it from the answer itself, but that doesn't mean I can't do it for fun ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that your J, L, and T tetrominoes actually have 5 squares each; I'm fairly sure that wasn't intentional.

Comment: The question describes things that happen when "enemy is dead", but does not describe what causes that or what happens when "you are dead".

Comment: @KamilDrakari `[On spawn] If a block can't fit, it will try to rotate, so it can be placed. If all 4 directions fail, you die.`

Comment: That is an awfully small section for something quite important. I would add a distinct section on Death, clarifying "when dead, you can no longer place blocks" and some edge cases for the 10 bonus pieces, such as what happens if a player dies during their bonus pieces and if they are required to continue placing the full 10 blocks or they can stop once they have a higher score.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Oh, you're right. I'll try to add something about that, when I have some time.

Comment: @ETHproductions I also noticed that J and L are pentominoes. T is actually a hexomino. But...

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks for pointing this out. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

## UTF-8 repair

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

UTF-8 is the standard by which most of the world operates. Software that was intended to take in other encodings have been modified or wrapped to use UTF-8 as input and output, some with bugs and/or sloppy adherence to the standard. Even rock-solid software with years-old implementations of UTF-8, such as Java, can contain numerous UTF-8 implementation errors.

### The challenge

Given a string of characters as input, apply a list of transformations to it. The transformations can be applied in any order, but should have the same  result as if the transformations were applied in the listed order.

- Replace overlong sequences with their equivalent minimal-length encodings.
- If a byte taking the form 0b11111xxx occurs, replace it, and up to three trailing bytes of the form 0b10xxxxxx, with a single replacement character (\uFFFD).
- Replace any run of extraneous bytes taking the form 0b10xxxxxx with a single replacement character.
- If a byte of the form 0b11xxxxxx is followed by an insufficient number of bytes of the form 0b10xxxxxx (either because of a byte of the borm 0b11xxxxxx or the end of the file/string), replace it and any trailing 0b10xxxxxx bytes with a single replacement character.
- Convert a high surrogate character followed by a low surrogate character to the utf-8 encoding of the supplemental plane codepoint it represents.
- Replace extraneous surrogate characters with the replacement character.
- Remove the initial byte order mark (\uFEFF), if one occurs at the start of the string.
- Keep all other characters intact. Make particular care to make sure that null characters are handled correctly.

The following are errors:

- An inverted byte order mark (\uFFFE) occurs at the start of a string.
- The transformed string consists of more than 16 codepoints, and more than 1/8 of them correspond to bad byte sequences.
- The input string consists of more than 32 bytes, and more than 1/8 of them do not correspond to a valid character, an overlong character, or a surrogate character.

If an error occurs, use an error indication mechanism (return a null pointer, utilize a tagged union indicating an error condition, set an global error variable, throw an exception, raise a signal, whatever), and do not output anything other than an optional error message. Otherwise, print the whole transformed string.

Standard loopholes apply. As with all code golf challenges, shortest submission wins.

### Test cases:

To be added if this submission gains traction.

Answer (score 0):

## Budget my lunch!

I'm a man of habit, but I also like to live quite frugally so every day I make myself the same lunch consisting of;

- 3 Falafel
- 2 Flatbreads
- A serving of houmous
- Some lettuce

Now in order to make sure I always put aside enough money for my lunch I need a program that will calculate the total cost of these ingredients for *x* number of days, and that is where you come in!

## The Challenge

Write a method that, when given two integers representing the start day and the number of days to calculate for, will return/print out a the total cost of my food for that number of days. There are several rules that this calculation follows;

- Each pack of falafel contains 8 falafels and costs £1.50. However, every three days I get lucky and the pack has 9 falafel in it!
- Each pack of flatbreads contains 6 flatbreads and costs £1.
- Each pot of houmous contains 4 servings and costs £1.10.
- Each head of lettuce provides 7 servings and costs 46p (£0.46).
- Houmous and flatbread both go off over the weekend/I eat them so have to be bought fresh on Monday.

## The Input

You will recieve two integers as input. These can be read from STDIN, passed as individual arguments, or passed as an array. Up to you.

The first integer represents the starting day e.g. 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday etc. This will always be between 1 and 5 inclusive.

The second integer is the number of days to budget for *not including weekends* e.g. an input of 1 and 5 would be budgeting my lunch for each day of the standard working week.

## Sample program

Below is a **throroughly ungolfed** program to use as reference and clarification of the above rules.

```
public static double budgetMyLunch(int startDay, int days){
    double totalCost = 0;

    final double falafelCost = 1.5;
    final int falafelsInPack = 8;
    int falafels = 0;
    int falafelPackCount = 0;

    final double flatbreadCost = 1;
    final double flatbreadsInPack = 6;
    int flatbreads = 0;

    final double houmousCost = 1.1;
    final int houmousServings = 4;
    int houmous = 0;

    final double lettuceCost = 0.46;
    final int lettuceServings = 7;
    int lettuce = 0;

    int endDay = startDay + days;
    int currentDay = startDay;

    while(currentDay<endDay){

        // If there are less than 3 falafels I have to buy some more
        if(falafels<3){
            falafelPackCount++;
            falafels += falafelsInPack;
            // Every third pack of falafel I get lucky and it has 9 instead of 8!
            if(falafelPackCount%3==0) falafels++;
            totalCost += falafelCost;
        }

        // If there are less than 2 flatbreads I have to buy some more
        if(flatbreads<2){
            flatbreads += flatbreadsInPack;
            totalCost += flatbreadCost;
        }

        // If there are no servings of houmous left I have to buy some more
        if(houmous == 0){
            houmous += houmousServings;
            totalCost += houmousCost;
        }

        // If there is no lettuce left I have to buy some more
        if(lettuce == 0){
            lettuce += lettuceServings;
            totalCost += lettuceCost;
        }

        // Use up the ingredients for my lunch!
        falafels -= 3;
        flatbreads -= 2;
        houmous -= 1;
        lettuce -= 1;

        // If it's the end of the week, I eat the remaining
        // houmous and flatbread over the weekend
        if(currentDay%5==0){
            houmous = 0;
            flatbreads = 0;
        }

        currentDay++;
    }
    return totalCost;
}
```

## Questions for sandbox

- Any suggested tags other than [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) ?
- Is the question of appropriate complexity to be an interesting challenge? Should I add more rules?
- Is the sample program required or are the rules clear enough on their own? If it is required should it be included in the question (as above) or linked through to somewhere like Pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

### Reverse a regex

The .NET regex engine has the ability to process a regex in right-to-left order. There are some subtle differences between right-to-left and left-to-right order, so for the purposes of this challenge, right-to-left order is equivalent to running a reversed regex on a reversed string.

But how do you reverse a regex? Aha, that's where you come in. You need to write a program or function that reads a regex and writes one that will match reversed strings.

Fortunately reversing regexes is quite simple: break them down into symbols and concatenate them in reverse order. The symbols you should support are as follows:

- Unquoted nonmagic characters
- Quoted characters
- Character classes (anything from `[` to an unquoted `]`)
- Symbols with repetition suffixes (assume that any of `+*?` or `{...}` is a valid repetition suffix)
- Parenthesised regexes (the inner regex will itself need to be reversed)

So for instance the reverse of `a{2,}(\*[b-g])+` is `([b-g]\*)+a{2,}`.

TODO: More examples, [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules, loopholes.

Should I add lookaheads/behinds to the list or is that too complex?

Comment: Character classes and repetition suffixes, at the very least, need more detail. Obviously some advanced repetition suffixes simply *can't* work, but which ones should be implemented?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't understand why they can't work. You'll be able to assume that the input is a valid regex, so you'll be able to treat `a+?` as the symbol `a+` with a suffix of `?`.

Comment: I had possessive quantifiers particularly in mind. I do retract the "*obviously*": now that I'm trying to think of an explicit example, it's not easy. But I'm still confident that one can be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

## Find local Minimum

**META**: This is just meant as an introductory challenge for functional input (black box functions) and hopefully establish some more inputs.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

Given a real number `e > 0` and some [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877) `f: (0,1) → (-10,10) ⊆ ℝ`, return a value `x` that is within `e` of a local minimum `x*` that means `x ∊ [x* - e, x* + e]`.

#### Details

- A value `x*` is *local minimum* of `f` if and only if there is some `a > 0` such that `f(x*) < f(x)` for all `x ∊ (x* - a, x* + a) \ {x*}`. This means all other points in some neighbourhood must have a strictly greater function value. (This definition is just for this challenge and might be different from other definitions.)
- The input function `f` can assumed to be differentiable and satisfy `f'(0) < 0` and `f'(1) > 0` which means there are no local minima at `0` and `1`.
- You can assume that `|f'(x)| < 1000` this means the function cannot be to steep.
- You can use your native floating point numbers and assume `e` is sufficiently great. (That means greater than the machine precision of your floating point type.)
- You can use any language for which there are defaults for black box functions input in the [standard IO meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). If there are no such default for your language feel free to add one in the sense of the [definition of black box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877), and make sure to link your proposals in that definition. Also don't forget to vote on them.

#### Examples

```
x*                 f(x)
0.5                x*(x-1)
0.5                (x+1/2)^(2*k-1) * (x-3/2)^(2*k-1) for k=1,2,...,1000 
2*(k+1/4)/(2*n-1)  -sin(pi*(2*n-1)) for n=1,2,3,...,159 (for every applicable k there is one minimum)
```

Comment: FWIW there was a black-box function question a long time ago: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3839/194 . On a separate issue, being differentiable is quite a weak condition: is it strong enough to make this answerable? I don't know the whole zoo of nasty counterexamples in analysis, but ISTM that to have a local minimum you need a second derivative, and to solve for a black box you probably want at least the second derivative to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You're right, right now it is not answerable, I found an counterexample, and also with requiring second derivatives we can solve it as a black box function.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in main site. Got a very bad review. So, I would be glad if any kind soul here would like to help me make this question better. And Some feedback on how can i make it good.

Given any input, you need to encode / decode it in or from base 16, 32, 64.

So your task will be to make a base 16, 32, 64 encoder / decoder.

```
RULES:
Standard Loopholes apply.
and that's all
INPUT:
In any format you like.
The inputs will be the 
i. Data
ii. Task (encoding or decoding) (0 or 1)
iii. Base (16 or 32 or 64)

Output:
The Encoded/Decoded data
```

The shortest code in byte wins.

Reference : [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)

Comment: Just as a starter, I would remove the "It should not be a builtin" (see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/66833)) Secondly, rather than link to a website with a description of what you mean, include that description in your question. Finally, allow function answers, rather than restricting to a full program.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks. I will add those changes

Answer (score 0):

## The Guardian of the Chessboard

Given a collection of chess squares<sup>1</sup>, output the chess piece with the smallest value, together with its position, that is able to reach all the given squares in a single step.

<sup>1 - A chess square is a notation of a position on an 8x8 grid, with the x-axis being labeled with letters instead of numbers, meaning for example that the notation of **3|2** would be **c2**.</sup>

### Input

Input must be received as a collection of strings, each string representing a chess square. You may assume that the chess square will always be in the range a1 - h8.

**Example Input**: `[ "b7", "c4", "h1", "g8" ]`

### Output

Output must be  in the format `[piece][square]`, with piece being the notation of the chess piece, such as `N`, `Q` or `K`, and square being the notation of the square that the chess piece has to be located at.

You may either return a string from a method or directly output the result to `stdout`.

### Rules

- Note that you have to use the chess piece with the least possible value, so if there is a choice between for example Queen and Bishop, you would choose the Bishop. See below for a table noting the piece values.
- *Special moves* such as pawn's first move, en passent and castling do not have to be respected.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes, in any programming language wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Data Table

Here you can look up each pieces value and its notation character.

```
|  Piece | Value | Character |
|:------:|:-----:|:---------:|
| Pawn   | 1     | P         |
| King   | 2     | K         |
| Knight | 3     | N         |
| Bishop | 3     | B         |
| Rook   | 5     | R         |
| Queen  | 9     | Q         |
```

---

### Test Cases

```
Input -> Output

[ "b7", "c4", "h1", "g8" ] -> Bd5
```

(TODO: Add more testcases)

---

## Sandboxing

- Duplicates?
- Possible misunderstatings?
- Task changes?

Comment: Reach in exactly 1 step? Is 0 step allowed? What about multiple steps?

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, clarified.

Comment: Needs a mention of special cases (pawn's first move, en passant, castling): should we assume that none of them are available?

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's correct, I added it to the rules section, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Ternary Parity of Substrings

### Definition

The ternary parity of a string is the number of 1's in its ascii bitstring mod 3.  For instance, the ascii values for `"Hello World!"` are:

`H:72 e:101 l:108 l:108 o:111 space:32 W:87 o:111 r:114 l:108 d:100 !:33`

Converting each ascii value to binary gives:

`H:1001000 e:1100101 l:1101100 l:1101100 o:1101111 space:100000
W:1010111 o:1101111 r:1110010 l:1101100 d:1100100 !:100001`

Concatenating these together gives the combined bitstring:

1001000110010111011001101100110111110000010101111101111111001011011001100100100001

Which has 45 1's.  As a result, the ternary parity of `"Hello World!"` is 45%3 = 0.

### Challenge

Write the shortest program in the language of your choice that does the following:

- Takes a string, s, as input.
- Finds S, the collection of all substrings of s
- Calculates the ternary parity of each element of S
- Creates a ternary string, q, by concatenating the parity bits of each element in S
- Outputs the ternary parity of q.  That is, the number of 1's in q mod 3.

### Input/Output

Input and output may use any of the standard methods listed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods%20/%20here).  The program must output three distinct values that indicate ternary parity.  For instance, the program could print "one", "two", or "three", it could exit with an error code of 0, 1, or 2, or could be a function that returns False for 1 and Null for 2, and 100 for 0, etc.

### Test Cases

```
"Hello World!" => 0
"foobar" => 2
"ABCDEFG" => 1
"abcdefg" => 0
"One" => 2
"Four" => 0
"2049" => 1
```

Comment: One element of a good question is a clear motivation. This looks like a random mishmash of operations. Why should anyone care about the result of this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

## Clear the centrally significant on bits

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)

[Related and inspired by.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148049/clearing-the-most-significant-bit-from-an-integer)

## **Input**

Input is a single positive integer `n`.

## **Output**

It's easiest to describe this by example.

```
n = 433
```

Take `n`'s binary representation.

```
bin(n) = 110110001
```

Note which bits are on.

```
110110001
^^ ^^   ^
```

Set the center bit of those that are on to `0`.  (if there is an even number of `1` bits, set both to `0`).

```
110010001
^^ !^   ^
```

Finally, represent the input as an integer again.

```
unbin(110010001) = 401
```

### Test cases

```
1 => 0
13 => 9
115 => 99
236 => 204
433 => 401
732 => 652
1555 => 1539
1556 => 1028
```

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/75524) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Bring an end to the Vigil

[Vigil](https://github.com/munificent/vigil), being the supreme moral paragon of programming languages, inspires us all to write bug-free code without exceptions through supreme medieval punishment.

However, every hero has their weakness, and [Vigil's weakness is on line 98](https://github.com/munificent/vigil/blob/master/vigil#L98):

```
except:
    print("Vigil has failed to uphold supreme moral vigilance.")
```

Your goal is to write a Vigil program that forces Vigil to experience an exception, reach this line, and print this error. Because it's not enough to merely succeed at our master plans, but instead we ought to succeed *efficiently,* the shortest answer in bytes wins.

---

#### Draft proposal notes

- This is a language-specific challenge in the Vigil language alone. (Is there a tag for that?)
- I'm not sure if a standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge is the best way to measure a winner in this scenario, but it's the primary measure that comes to mind.
- I'd like to ham this up a bit more with narrative. Maybe about us being the villains. The title could be wittier.

Answer (score 0):

## Inverse Radiation Hardened Quine

### Background

Radiation hardened quines have been around for a long time. The basic idea is that it's (possibly) a valid quine, and if you remove any character, it's still valid. But what about the other way around? What if you added a character?

### Challenge Description

Develop a program which will output its source code, even when a character is inserted in any position in the source code.

### Input

This program is a quine. It shouldn't take any input.

### Output

When the quine runs, it should either output its own source code, or the source code of the proto-quine.

### Scoring

Programs are scored on their robustness. That is, for a given program, if the characters "a", "!"  or "" could be put into the program at any point and it remain a quine, then the program has a score of 3. I leave the burden of testing what characters work for your program up to you. Note that in languages with a limited character set (such as HQ9+ or brainfuck) characters that do nothing yield no score. You couldn't write a normal quine in brainfuck and then claim that every single unicode codepoint except the few used in a brainfuck program was your score.

Finally, other than that, standard rules apply.

Comment: Not a bad challenge, but could use some more fleshing out.  Take a look at the framework of some other challenges, both here and in main, to see what the usual framework is.

Comment: To clarify, I mean specifically the usual: brief story about the challenge (optional), "Your Task:", task, "Input:" input methods, "Output:", output methods, "Examples:", examples, "Scoring:", scoring method.  That framework works well for most challenges

Comment: Can we chose where the character is inserted?

Comment: @ATaco no, it has to be valid for anywhere. Otherwise, somebody would make a safety box for the character.

Comment: I would suggest clarifying your scoring section, specifically specifying "robustness" better.  I'm pretty sure I get what you mean, but others may misinterpret that.  Other than that, this looks like a great challenge.  +1

Comment: Is the emoji bad? I put it in there to demonstrate únicode, but I'm not sure the point is that obvious.

Comment: Nah, it's fine.  The example makes it more clear.  I might add something to specifically say that it doesn't count if a character can be inserted twice (or at least, that's my understanding of the rules), but other than that, you should be good.

Comment: To be certain, when you say it should output "it's own source code, or the source code of the proto-quine" then, after a character is added, your code may either output the original code or the modified code? Is it alright if a single submission does one or the other depending on the type or location of the inserted character?

Comment: @KamilDrakari yeah, as long as it does do at least one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

## Rhythm Generator

**Your task**: given a number `n` from 2 to 5 inclusive, (pseudo)randomly generate a valid rhythm in the time signature `n/4`, and output using the system explained below. It must have an equal chance of choosing each valid rhythm.

#### Background Information:

In music, collections of beats are called "measures." You can only fit a certain number of beats in a measure, determined by the time signature. For example, a time signature of `4/4` would mean that you can put 4 (as determined by the first number) quarter note (determined by the second number) beats in the measure.

There are different kinds of notes. For the purposes of this challenge, the following characters will represent different kinds of notes (and how many quarter note beats each one is worth):

```
W        Whole note                4
H        Half note                 2
K        Dotted Half note          3
Q        Quarter note              1
D        Dotted Quarter note       1.5
E        Eighth note               0.5
F        Dotted Eighth note        0.75
S        Sixteenth note            0.25
```

<sub>(There are other kinds of notes but they do not apply to this challenge)</sub>

Note: A dotted note takes 1.5 of the length of its non-dotted counterpart.

In a `n/4` measure there can only be `n` quarter note beats. Some notes take more than a beat, some less. But the total number of beats needs to add up to `n`.

For example, here are some valid `4/4` measures (separated by newlines):

```
W
HH
QQQQ
EEEEEEEE
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
KEE
EQQQE
```

And here are some examples of valid `3/4` measures:

```
K
DD
QQQ
QDE
```

So, your task is to generate a rhythm and output it in that format.

**So now let's make some music!**

#### Test Cases:

Coming soon. Will be a complete list of all possible valid rhythms.

Answer (score 0):

## View float numbers in graphical binary

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is a well known format for representing floating point numbers.

Your task is to give an input to the user where he/she enters a signed float number and represents clearly the number in a color separated by functional area binary 32 bit single representation, like:

[image]

- You do not have to append the captions like they are in the figure.
- You must follow the order Sign, Exponent, Fraction
- You may choose whatever colors you want, as they are distinguishable from each other and from the binary text numbers.
- The input (I suggest a text box) does not have to forbid invalid values, but if does not, the graphical binary view needs to indicate the invalidity. You can leave it empty or replace with some text like "ERROR" or "INVALID".
- Every little change on the input needs to make the binary view to be immediately updated. Changing and have to confirm with an "OK" like button is not acceptable.

No winner, unless I see some very creative answer.
I would like to see a golfed and an ungolfed version of the code.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [floating-point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion)

Comment: Needing the output to be dynamically updated based on the input changing (and not an OK or the like) is going to drastically limit the languages that can participate.

Comment: Additionally to what @AdmBorkBork said, the requirement of dynamically updating the output & validating input is just distracting from the real challenge. I'd just leave behaviour on invalid input undefined.

Answer (score 0):

## Examining the Student's Swing

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The [2017 Level 1 Mathematics and Statistics NCEA examination paper](http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2017/91028-exm-2017.pdf) has been making [headlines in New Zealand](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11946237) for being 'impossible' and bringing students to tears.

One of the questions involves a children's playground swing, and finding where the holes in the swing seat should be placed. But lets generalise the problem in code in the fewest number of bytes, in case they have to solve for a different swing (in a different exam).

#### Task

Find how far apart the holes in the board need to be if the shape of the rope stays the same, given the following swing setup:

- The rope hangs from a cross beam at a height `h`, and will have a *parabolic* shape, as presented in the exam (rather than a catenary shape), and will maintain this shape with the seat.
- The rope is connected to the crossbeam at two points, that are separated by a distance `d`.
- The lowest point (vertex) of the rope sits above the ground at a height of `v`.
- We have an adequately sized wooden board for the seat, and we want this to be at a height `s` above the ground.

Exam questions often have a visual representation to help clarify the question, so I've also included one:

[image]

#### Rules

- inputs must take positive real values
- `s` will be greater than `v`
- output must be correct to at least 2dp.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), therefore, the lowest byte count in each programming language wins
- Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, and no [forbidden loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

#### Test Cases

```
(h,d,v,s) -> hole separation
(4, 6, 1, 1.2) -> 1.549
(10, 4, 2, 4) -> 2
(14.5, 12, 2.5, 5.5) -> 6
(4.25, 3.4, 0.5, 1.2) -> 1.468
```

#### Sandbox Questions

- First time question, so any recommendations would be great
- Any recommendations for how I can make this a well received question?
- are there any rules I'm missing, or should add?
- is this a duplicate?
- What other tags should this question have?

Comment: About the `output must be correct to at least 2dp.` part, I'm afraid that there will be some problems from that requirement. A better requirement is "the algorithm in the code must be able to theorically calculate to infinite precision, but numerical error from programming language type limit is acceptable". / Also, the "the rope is always in parabolic shape" is weird, is that correct? If so you should highlight it. (normally a unweighed rope has catenary shape, and a weighed rope has the shape of multiple straight line segment) / Otherwise the challenge looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; the `2dp` was based on the exam question requirement of showing your working to 2dp, though I understand the precision issue. Maybe I just remove that rule? I didn't know about catenary shape, the exam question just used a parabola, so I'll highlight that fact.

Comment: So in other words, given `(h,d,v,s)` output `d sqrt((s-v)/(h-v))`. I don't think it's a duplicate, but I also think that the reason that it isn't is because everyone has previously (and correctly) concluded that calculating a square root without restrictions to prohibit builtin sqrt functions is too trivial to be worth posting.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, (you know) on this site it is generally discouraged to post a "puzzle", because once the first answer had been posted, the other answers can just use that - and your comment has already specified the method. / You meant `sqrt` should be prohibited? That will lead to the (well-known) do X without Y problem.

Comment: @user202729, no, I did not mean that. I meant that "Calculate sqrt without a builtin sqrt" would be a duplicate (although maybe only of closed questions). See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73/194 and linked questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor This exam question certainly simplified down to a trivial coding answer; I think I was more posting due to the story behind it. I'll have a think about if or how to make it a bit more challenging. Will just mean that it may not be as closely related to the exam question on which it is based.

Answer (score 0):

### Optimise Retina transliterations

For the question [Translate Morse code based on tone duration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148285/) I stupidly created the following transliteration:

```
T`T\EMNAI\OGKDWRUSJ2V\HBZ89#@`NIGDRS8ZCBP\LF\H12356789_`\w@#
```

The first thing wrong with it is that it `2`, `8` and `9` transliterate to themselves, so they are superfluous. This saves 6 bytes:

```
T`T\EMNAI\OGKDWRUSJV\HBZ#@`NIGDRS8ZCBP\LF\H13567_`\w@#
```

The next thing to notice is that we have some runs of consecutive letters, but because they're not ordered we can't reduce them. Let's sort them:

```
T`ABD\EG\HIJKMN\ORSTUVWZ#@`R6BIZ5S1CGD8\L\HNF3P7`\w@#
```

We can now save another 3 bytes by using the run `G-K`, a byte by using the run `M-O`, and 3 bytes by using the run `R-W`:

```
T`ABD\EG-KM-OR-WZ#@`R6BIZ5S1CGD8\L\HNF3P7`\w@#
```

Total 13 bytes saved. Note that there are other optimisation opportunities but I think they might be too difficult be worth adding to the question; for instance, inserting a `C` (at a cost of 2 bytes) allows the creation of the run `A-E` for a 3-byte saving, which is still overall a byte saved; inserting all of the letters to achieve run `A-Z` would then be simplified to `L`.

Is the Retina command string too inflexible an input format? I suppose input could be in the form of an unordered mapping from printable ASCII to printable ASCII, but output would need to be the actual Retina syntax, including appropriate quoting, because the length of the result is important.

(Quoting: The characters `` -dEOHhLlwpoR`\ `` need to be quoted except that the letters don't need to be quoted as part of a range.)

Should this be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question or [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)?

Answer (score 0):

## A Knight's Walk

On a chessboard, a knight has two options for movement: it can move one square horizontally and two squares vertically, or two squares horizontally and one square vertically. In short, it can follow the path drawn by an upper-case "L". These can be oriented in any way, and as such, a knight has 8 potential moves from any given position.

There have been a number of challenges posted at one time or another regarding knights and their movement because they're so mathematically interesting (and the problems are easy to state) but we're going to go for a basic one that I haven't seen.

### The Challenge

Given two 2d coordinates `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` return the minimum number of moves required to travel from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`.

There are no other pieces on the board, and you may assume that the coordinate values given are valid (a set of two integers) though they may not be unique. You may also assume that each individual coordinate value will be between 0 and 255, and that the board is large enough that you needn't consider edges.

### Input Format

As long as the coordinates are inputted in the order `x1 y1 x2 y2` you can accept them as four separate values, two tuples, two lists, etc...

### Examples

```
(0, 0) (1, 2) => 1
(0, 0) (1, 1) => 2
(125, 125) (126, 127) => 1
(-100, -100) (0, 100) => 100
```

Comment: You might want to more explicitly state that negative numbers must be supported. Also, 'less than 128' applies only to inputs? or to anything?

Comment: Will do! And I'm not sure what you mean by that second part: I mean the input values will individually have absolute values of less than 128 a.k.a. (-127, -127) to (127, 127). This is totally a point I'm flexible on though. I just figured there may be languages that don't support very large numbers in any given memory location, and didn't want to give them additional hoops to jump through.

Edit: Should I just make the valid range 0-255?

Comment: I'd recommend making it 0-255, yeah.  I don't really think it's fair to have input be -127, +127, and then the boundaries of the chesboard be infinity. 
 That's just kinda contradictory.

Comment: Do you think I should keep a bound like 255 at all? Would 2^16-1 or 2^32-1 be better? My whole premise with picking a number like this was that I want it to be easy to represent any number you'd run into, but impossible to use any kind of naive recursion to solve it

Comment: "impossible to use any kind of naive recursion to solve it" - Why? I don't understand your argument. / **What is the winning criteria?**

Comment: @Willbeing I think 255 is fine, it doesn't matter too much. I've seen successful challenges that only require you to support up to 255, but that's it.

Comment: @user202729 Yeah, it sounds odd when its played back to me, hahaha. I only care if the program deterministically produces the correct step count. I still think limiting the input size is probs a good idea, just not for that reason anymore.

Answer (score 0):

## Clean duplicate website from my history

[coge-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coge-golf)

### Introduction

I am looking for help to monitor my history. I parsed everything, but I am not yet happy with the final result. Could you help me?
I want to remove following same website.

My history looks like this:

```
| url                                               | id |
|---------------------------------------------------|----|
| https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147318/15214 | 4  |
| https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148927/15214 | 4  |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf           | 3  |
| http://lichess.org                                | 2  |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_poetry         | 1  |
```

But I want it to be:

```
| url                                               | id |
|---------------------------------------------------|----|
| https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148927/15214 | 4  |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf           | 3  |
| http://lichess.org                                | 2  |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_poetry         | 1  |
```

- If I browse a site, then another one, then the first one. I keep all of them.
- If I browse a site, then another part of the same site. I keep only the first one.
- The list is ordered from young to old. (we keep the older)

This challenge is inspired by my day work, but it is not related in any ways with anything in it.

### Challenge

- Input is a list of identifier.
- Output is a list of two elements (identifier's index, identifier).
- No Empty input
- No standard loophole
- This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Examples Input and Output

#### 2 links on website 1

Input:

```
[ 1, 1 ]
```

Output:

```
[
    [1,1]
]
```

#### 1 link on website 2, then 3 links on website 1

Input:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[
    [2,1],
    [3,2]
]
```

#### 1 link on website 1, then 1 link on website 2, then 2 link on website 1

Input:

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Output

```
[
    [1,1],
    [2,2],
    [3,1]
]
```

---

### Question

- Should I allow outputs as list of object, list of tuple or dictionary/map?
- Should I ask for url parsing where identifier is the hostname?

Comment: Question title and tag?

Comment: Also I think the I/O specification (Input is a list of two elements. / Output is a list of two elements.") seems to contradict the test cases.

Comment: @user202729 Update title, tag and I/O specs. Thank you.

Comment: You definitely should allow using tuples, maps and dictionaries for input and output. In fact, that's an understatement. You should read the meta post on I/O methods. URL parsing will make the challenge more interesting, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

## DNA Quine

### Problem Description

Design a quine that outputs its own source code, but encoded into amino acids.
Read your source code in as binary. 
Each pair of bits now maps to a nucleotide like so:

```
00 -> A
01 -> C
10 -> G
11 -> T
```

For example, the ASCII character `N` has a binary representation of `01001110`, so it would produce the nucleotide sequence `CATG`. 
A set of three nucleotides produces an amino acid. You can find the charts online, and I can't access imgur, so... yeah.

Anyways, your program must output its own source code as the three letter amino acid names. For example, if your code were `013201323300` in base 4, its nucleotide representation would be `ACTGACTGTTAA` and its amino acid representation would be `ThrAspCysSTP`.

### Output

Your program must output its representation in amino acids.

### Further Rules

All quines must also be valid proteins themselves. This means that:

- The quine has a number of nucleotides divisible by three
- The last three nucleotides are either `TAG`, `TAA`, or `TGA`, corresponding to a `STP` codon
- No `STP` codons appear anywhere but the end of the quine.

Apart from that, the standard rules apply.

### Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

## Notes/Questions for Sandboxing

Ok, so I get that it's rather short. Is my point clear? Is the scoring section clear? How about loopholes? Should I point out that printing a single `STP` is not allowed? Would that even be possible?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on _"expand it into base 4"_. Does that mean get each byte's codepoint, concatenate into one big binary integer, and then convert to base 4?

Comment: What happens if the number of nucleotide is not a multiple of 3? | The base 4 conversion is indeed unclear.

Comment: @user202729 if there's a spare nucleotide, it's not a valid program.

Comment: So basically "program length must be a multiple of 3". / For example program `00 FF` should be `00 00 00 00 11 11 11 11` = `AAAATTTT` or `TTTTAAAA`?

Comment: Yeah, essentially. Except that some code golf languages have special character sets that aren't 8 bits, and some trickster out there might use that.

Comment: @JakobLovern Unless there are some computers that can store fractional byte size, that won't be accepted.

Comment: I have no idea how to convert `CATG` into amino acids. Challenges should be self-contained.

Comment: I suspect most answers will be of the form "1. get string of source code by standard quine technique" and "2. convert string into dna form", so the first part doesn't add anything to the challenge. I'd suggest to change the task to write a program which translates a given string into your DNA format.

Answer (score 0):

## Information Masking

> Email Address Masking:

Only show the first and last characters of the username components of an email address, along with email domain name. Include 5 stars in the middle of the username to mask the length. The username part of the email address may use any of the ASCII characters listed below.

### Rules

1. Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
2. Digits 0 to 9
3. Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ { | } ~
4. Character . (dit, period, full stop) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively.
5. It is provided that email should end with `@domainName.com`, where the domain name has only alphabetic characters.
6. It is provided that email address username part have at least 2 characters not starting and ending with a special character.

### Example

`JackAndJill@gmail.com --> j*****l@gmail.com`

> Phone number masking:

### Rules

Mask all the digits in a phone number except the last 4 digits. Each number should be replaced by star(*). Input phone numbers can be with or without the country code. Input Phone numbers can only have +, (, ), - in them along with numbers and spaces. Make sure + is not masked in the output and make sure the number of stars is equal to the number of digits while masking.Phone numbers will always have 10 digits without country code and with the country code, they could be up to 13 digits.

### Examples

```
Example1: +1 (333) 444-5678  --> +*-***-***-5678  
Example2: +91 (333) 444-5678 ->  +**-***-***-5678  
Example3: 333 444 5678 --> ***-***-5678  
Example4: (333) 444-5678 ---> ***-***-5678
```

Program input will start with E: for email and P: for phone numbers, ignore spaces if they are found in the input.

### Complete Program Example

**Input:**

```
E: jackAndJill@gmail.com  
P: +13334445678
```

**Output:**

```
E: j*****l@gmail.com  
P: +*-***-***-5678
```

Comment: How does `hackAndJill` start with a `j`?

Comment: Just a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: The examples show phone numbers of various different formattings what is it? Why are `-` in the output where in the input were only numbers how does that work? Is input always valid, can input be only a phone number etc. What about email addresses such as `user@remote` or `u@remote.net`?

Comment: The input number can be in any format as the given in the example. And it is should be output in the form that last phone numbers are shown and then a `-`, then every 3 numbers are masked as `***` and a `-` after it until the numbers do not end.

Comment: Email address rules are updated.

Comment: What is the winning criterion? Code-golf?

Comment: Yes, code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

### Find and execute a program from the internet [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

You have some task to do, but you are too lazy to do it yourself. Your also to lazy to make a program to do it. So you are going to make a program that finds a program to do the task you want.

Select a programming language Q (which must be Turing complete).

Your program will:

1. Take an input task, as a string, and input, as a string.
2. Search codegolf.stackexchange.com, using the input string as the query
3. Select the first question in the search results with an answer which contains a valid Q program. (If there is no such question, the operation of your program may be undefined.) (You may assume that program is in a code block.)
4. Select either the accepted answer if it contains a valid Q program, or the highest voted answer that contains a valid Q program.
5. Execute the Q program that that answer contains, using the input from step 1.

Since you are lazy, you want your program to be the shortest program possible. So this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins!

Comment: What happens if the search result finds your answer?

Comment: @Neil Fixed it.

Comment: I don't know enough about the API to say, but can the order of results be changed by changing the search query to only allow questions? It seems like the searching may result in people trying to work around doing some API work, and it will be a pain to check. This isn't really a problem, just something I think you should know before posting.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm not sure. Think it would be better if I allow people to change the search query to only questions?

Comment: I think that would make it easier, but it kind of results in two separate golfing tasks: minimising the search query and minimising the code to parse/execute answers. I'm not sure of a good way to resolve that (or if it is that bad) but it does give me the feeling that it may be better split up in some way.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I could allow them to take a search query string template as input (or just say that it doesn't count towards their score). That way, there is no need to golf it.

Comment: What if the result takes no/more than one input? If Q is chosen well enough, you get away with a nop.. so this becomes a quest of finding languages unused on PPCG. What happens if these then get added?

Comment: @BruceForte It will be fed into the program via standard input. I said that Q must be Turing complete, which means it must take input.

Answer (score 0):

## Thou shall permute!

Given a string of upper and/or lower case letters and/or numbers (or list of characters if you want),
 and a list of permutation cycles, compute every intermediate step of applying this permutation under the following rules:

- The space to move letters around is one row above and one row below the input, with the same length available as the string length.
- In the beginning, top and bottom row are empty, and the middle row contains the whole string
- A character can only take the spot of another character, if that spot is empty
- There can only be at most one character in the top row and one in the bottom row at any time
- You can only move one character in one direction per state change.
  Directions are:

  1. Out of the middle top or down
  2. Left/Right (any number of steps at once)
  3. Into the middle

### Cyclic Permutations

I'm assuming 0 based indexing.
A list of cyclic permutations looks like this (I'm assuming list of tuples, but I don't mind if you want something else, as long as it conveys the same idea):

```
[(0,2,3),(1,4)]
```

This would mean that:

- index 0 goes to index 2, index 2 goes to index 3, index 3 goes to index 0
- index 1 goes to index 4, index 4 goes to index 1

### Examples:

I'm using the `-`character to show available spots here, you may use a space or any character that can not be contained in the input string, such as `#`or `$`.

Given the string `test` and the cyclic permutations `[(0,2)(1,3)]`, the steps would look as follows:

```
----
test  #Start state
----

----
-est  # Move index 0 out 
t---

--s-  
-e-t  # Move index 2 to the other side
t---

--s-
-e-t  # Move index 0 to where it needs to go
--t-

--s-
-ett  # Insert index 0 at index 2
----

s---
-ett  # Move index 2 to where it needs to go
----

----
sett  # Insert index 2 at index 0
----

----
s-tt  # Move index 1 out
-e--

---t
s-t-  # Move index 3 out
-e--

---t
s-t-  # Move index 1 to index 3
---e

---t
s-te  # Insert index 1 at index 3
----

-t--
s-te  # Move index 3 to index 1
----

----
stte # Insert index 3 at index 1. Done.
----
```

Here is the same example again, but this time using only one long permutation of all characters: `[(0,2,1,3)]` instead of 2 independent permutations:

```
----
test
----

----
-est
t---

--s-
-e-t
t---

--s-
-e-t
--t-

--s-
-ett
----

--s-
--tt
-e--

-s--
--tt
-e--

----
-stt
-e--

---t
-st-
-e--

---t
-st-
---e

---t
-ste
----

t---
-ste
----

----
tste
----
```

### Rules

- You will only receive valid cyclic permutations
- Please indicate if you want 0 or 1 indexed permutations, either is fine
- You will only receive valid strings up to length 10
- Characters in the string are **not** guaranteed to be unique
- it does not matter which order every permutation is processed as long as they're all processed (that means start and end states are the same, and the above rules are always fulfilled)
- There will be at least one permutation in the list of permutations
- All permutations in the list of permutations have at least length 2
- The maximal length of one permutation is the length of the input string
- There may be some indices that are not part of any permutation
- No index is part of more than one permutation
- You need to output the first step, the last step and all intermediate steps
- You may have as many trailing newlines and spaces as you want
- You may output a 2 dimensional array or anything equivalent instead of printing every step, or you can also return a list of all states in the end
- You can also generate an animation if you like instead of printing sequentially
- Lowest number of bytes wins
- Standard loopholes are forbidden
- You can write a full program or function

### Test cases

I implemented a very un-golfed version in python3 [here (redirects to repl.it)](https://repl.it/repls/ShadyPlumHoneycreeper).
That code contains 2 functions. 
`find_cycles` takes a string and a permutation of that string and computes the cycles to go from one to the other.
`shuffle` does the shuffling. It takes the start string and the cycles.
You can use these functions to validate your program.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [permutation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutation)

Answer (score 0):

Given an Integer array:

1. Start from the first number (n)
2. Go forward (n) positions depending on the current position
3. Delete the current position, the rest of the array `fill in` to the current position.
4. Goto step 2 until there are one number remaining
5. Print that number

The array loops around (the next number after the last number in the array is the first number).

A zero removes itself.

Negative numbers are not allowed as input.

**Test Cases**

```
[1] => 1
[1,2] => 1
[1,2,3] => 3
[1,2,2] => 1
[1,2,3,4] => 1
[6,2,3,4] => 4
[1,2,3,4,5] => 5
[0,1] => 1
[0,0,2,0,0] => 0
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins!

---

**Step-by-step example**

```
[1,4,2,3,5]
 ^          start from the first position
   ^        jump 1 position (value of the position)
[1,  2,3,5] remove number in that position
     ^      take next position of the removed number
         ^  jump 2 positions
[1,  2,3  ] remove number in that position
 ^          take next position (looping on the end of the array)
     ^      jump 1 position
[1,    3,5] remove number in that position
       ^    take next position (looping)
       ^    jump 3 positions (looping on the end of the array)
[1,      5] remove number in that position
         ^  take next position
 ^          jump 5 positions (looping)
[        5] remove number in that position
print 5
```

**Example #2**

```
[4,3,2,1,6,3]
 ^            start from the first position
         ^    jump 4 positions
[4,3,2,1,  3] remove number in that position    
           ^  take next position
     ^        jump 3 positions
[4,3,  1,  3] remove number in that position    
       ^      take next position
           ^  jump 1 positions
[4,3,  1    ] remove number in that position    
 ^            take next position
   ^          jump 4 positions
[4,    1    ] remove number in that position    
       ^      take next position
 ^            jump 1 position
[      1    ] remove number in that position
print 1
```

---

**Note:** This is my first challenge so any input is welcome.

Comment: After the step 2 where is the "pointer"?

Comment: The third step is worded a bit oddly, but I think I've understood it correctly from the examples. Do you mean that the elements after the deleted element are shifted to fill in the gap? It may be worth having one example written out step by step to make it easier for people to grasp what is happening.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I have edited the question to include 2 step-by-step examples. Can you help me word the third step more clearly? Perhaps: 2- jump forward n positions where n is the value of the current position. 3- delete the position you just arrived at. 4- the (new) current position is the next position. repeat step 2.

Comment: Problem title ?

Comment: That is better, but maybe roll it into one? "Delete the current position, making what was the next position the current position"

Comment: @user202729  Haven't decided yet, Maybe "Football Jersey Josephus" or a variation of Duck, Duck, Goose.

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a number

Create a program or function, which when given an input integer, outputs a mathematical expression evaluating to the same value. Expressions which require fewer bytes to represent than the integer itself will achieve better scores!

### Explanation

It is often useful when golfing to compress constant integer expressions by expressing them in the form of an equivalent mathematical expression. `387420489` for example is much more efficiently expressed as `9^9`. Similarly  `4194303` as `2^22-1`

The challenge is, for each integer in the range `1 to 1E6`, to golf the number into as short an expression as you can (although any expression which evaluates correctly is acceptable output, see **Rules** below). The shorter the expression, the better your score; but short programs will also score well so the two need to be balanced!

### Rules:

**Input** integer as argument or from STDIN

**Output** as string or equivalent to STDOUT or as function output. Your string can only contain ascii characters [`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`], as well as those operators defined below, repetitions allowed.

You may use the following mathematical operators any number of times in your string:

```
() parentheses
^ exponentiation
* multiplication
/ division
\ integer(floor) division - see Test Evaluator
+ addition
- subtraction
```

*NB: division, integer division and multiplication are all evaluated with equal priority, so `3/2\2 = 0` whereas `3\2/2 = 0.5`*

You may output the input value (if it can't be golfed for example), **you do not have to output the perfectly golfed string:**

```
 In: 10000

Out: 10000
     10^4
     2^13+1808
```

However the output must evaluate exactly to the input (assuming perfect precision of floats)

### Scoring

Answers are scored on their compression ratio (how much they golf the input down on average), as well as program size

**`Program Size`**: byte count of program (as with normal code golf)

**`Compression Ratio`**: `golfed Length (white-space ignored) / input Length`

**`Individual Score`**  =  `(Compression Ratio * 100 - 70)/6 + Log(Program Size, base 10)`

**`Final Score`** = `Mean score for first 10^6 integers`

**Lowest final score for each language wins!**

Tags:

[expression-building](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-building)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

---

## Sandbox:

[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139765/68602)

[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76591/express-a-number-with-only-0-9-and-the-four-operations)

The main sticking point is scoring **how best can you combine 2 metrics into a single score?**

The logic so far is that compression ratios will lie in the range 100 - 70 % where 100 is returning the input. Program lengths should be between 2 extremes; returning the input (1 byte) and looking up the input in a hardcoded list (~19,000,000 bytes). This gives the following distribution:

[image: Score table]

Actual program length I guestimate will be anywhere in the range 1 to 10000 bytes, hence the `log` to make the range more manageable. Quick reference; I could probably implement all power golfing (expressing n as a^b) in ~100-200 bytes in VBA. So 10% of that for golfing languages, and who knows what builtins Mathematica has ;).

But implementing more effective algorithms may require a more verbose language, so I think 1 - 10000 seems like a good range to handle in scoring

Open to alternative scoring though, and any required clarifications. Also suggestions **what is a good range to test over?**

I've suggested `1 to 1E6`; The first 1000 integers I don't *think* are golfable, after that only a few are. So perhaps a greater range of test cases, or ones starting at a larger initial value? What's the biggest range I can feasibly test within say, 10 mins running time max? What's typical algorithm execution times can be expected per digit? I don't want golfers to have to spend too long generating their average score...

[Test String Evaluation](https://tio.run/##rVdLc9s2ED5LvwLjQwRaFhXZh0xNu5lOk@bSpJ04PUVJBVOQCIcEGQC0ldr67e4uCFJ8yfZ4woNEPL5vX8Du8opds0macXm1/HYvkixVhlzBnJ8bEfsXIZOSq2CY5ZexCEkYM63JeyYkub3XhhmYu0zTmDNJlnytONfknKxYrHmFcduWKQw54dcspishWUwujBJyDevKI7dDAo/iJleSSH5D/rq84qGh5Qo@QhqSpShgMjsiYRQMq6XrVCwBtjG/R0w1QPiEEWDoeIzgM5Tnx1yuTUQ9j7y24xBgvxkKGzxyCvRBhd/uhJSGcmYo6oKgT@lbZtrybiIBllIUe05GZOTVVAsaO8Wq3LaXDJ998JrPjMp5c3E77NnmQtNjnYtPxpTmHQ/uU8CBNuBfC3y7yRTXWqSyz9I@/5tIpTc24h9zaUQCFCHPDDIc/ANiMzgFfHlKDsgYXcWUF0Ytamfaptes6ZS8UyxJmDqtz/FKUVDdcJWQu/rcYrzom50Us3UiuwuPfGhSBdvteHG4aM9My5k62O05t/IqAIrZDeiioYK3qBO4547IPLnkuH@VyxC994ElfMfiXhZfKy16414PX@sEtCP9Caxqx3gFImgQ9J1gCL99KF6e0XgEkd@QcZMLDWLLpUD1OwQczq09RJZgUhBMugQ6vzSKhfs5uqeleVm6V8KkH9lSMKlpORFxw9DKwcCxlbnvNeRGE/k7hNt6WmCC4WDPjSsseMTnf9jQPdvrh4XTDtts6LYkj43IIF2zJ3h/WhBN@4iW4lrgAQLfNEHzeYE6L1y0ilPAAEmToyCxi@SNoypU@FnRbIhr@axS1h5Qx921MZdM/SBZnOt@9KSGnuyDJ0ICvjfercwJpQZqqDJ/29pnIqF9yKRBv2yKsm9RDAjmEo6d5rrjuyckbOtiZPRGrZXt7jhg8foVatzLEXnxAuvsGQx@gYJ3d0dc@fNHTp8iRXV1cdXyiVQPlUK06o31oW@NK94pFhxIC9q2G7R05VHlSW@/fU4nVtfpv9KgMtW2TNpV/17oQwa4jgiJwZRH9e4S4FlRPIO4AX7Ws74qu5J/R30J47Fmoyi3jh@bIO@BxNQ5bPu3bftvd7@Cz2DsLEPStD2cAKaXgTgrjArEeLwnj1IMis@/59BA0QP9XZmDejrDCbrpu0LlUWrihWzChaS7orHxnkwUprpBBOPnERnW1AjGTyJ6uH/7JtMbWV2UoovDUW/A@i5hNxY/oWFsiapy59dGhcrSG7o56itPICSVkFtFUSwfbUbtr@8662AI4u@b30b28yWBrypaZIDPXwhTa21bDLiy@P755ZcqVtBtYKx2H1xF8z9wX2sEp9BBbkwvfmjDE19IED6w6YlqP2L6A9z0P4Xk2IdjM2OgLOH/wAHS3PgZ6GNiSe13m/blDoJk0M4MBtAzhBFtR4Nwbz@Zv@bmPdQdtkYmR7QFz2zvT@bH0@PhyfR4fjykJ5NXr7z5bObepvA2m9PZ9MS7B@v/Bw)

Comment: `requires fewer bytes to represent than the integer itself.` -- but you had said `The first 1000 integers I don't think are golfable`, so it doesn't work.

Comment: In your test, `2^13+1808` is longer than `10000`. It contradicts your problem statement. Also you don't allow `^` to be used. / Evaluate left to right?

Comment: `returning the input` is 0 byte in most languages, so the score would be `log(0) = -Infinity`.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139765/mathematical-expression-showdown).

Comment: @user202729 Your 1st point; I did include a sentence `you do not have to output the perfectly golfed string` in the rules section, but I'll fix the problem statement to match that. Good catch with `^`, I'll add that - but a longer expression is supposed to be acceptable. log(0) - well let's hope that's an incentive not to post trivial answers! But seriously, do you think it's worth adding a log(program length +1)? I don't think it is because it adds an additional layer of complexity to the scoring system - and people shouldn't really be entering trivial solutions anyway (I hope)

Comment: If they do post 0-byte solution and win, it's the fault of your scoring system. For reference, look at the score formula of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148639/find-the-password). --- You may want to add "you must calculate your score" to the question, like in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/build-a-fewest-moves-freecell-solver).

Comment: This isn't [tag:code-golf] - it's [tag:code-challenge].

Answer (score 0):

## All possible distributions of different items of a set to an arbitrary number of groups

See *Descriptive Real World Example*, *Rules / Edge Cases* or *Sample Data* for an idea about this or help me by adding a nice sentence explaining it while this is in sandbox.

## Descriptive Real World Example:

Ordering a set of `x` `items` from a shop what are the possibilities to distribute them among `1 to x` `orders`?

## Rules / Edge Cases

- Identical `items` are not being distinguished (`AB, B == AB, B`, compare examples `#4`, `#5` and `#6`)
- Order is ***not* important**

  - Order of `items` in `order`/`group`: `AB == BA`
  - Order of `orders`/`groups` in `distributions`: `A, B == B, A`
  - Order of possible `distributions` (i. e. lines among output)

## Format

I don't really mind the exact format but as it probably makes sense (right?) to tie oneself down to one format I'll suggest the following:

- Input: Set of items without delimiters. Supported chars: [A-Za-z0-9]
- Output:

  - Hierarchy: `Distributions (Orders (Items))`
  - Delimiters:

    - Among `distributions` in overall output: `EOL`
    - Among `orders`/`groups` in `distribution`: `Comma`, `Space`
    - Among `items` in `orders`/`groups`: `None`

## Sample Data

```
╔═════════╤═══════╤═════════╤════════════╗
║ Example │ Input │ Output  │   Output   ║
║   Nr    │       │ line nr │   lines    ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║   #1    │ A     │    1    │     A      ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │    A, A    ║
║   #2    │ AA    ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    2    │     AA     ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │    A, B    ║
║   #3    │ AB    ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    2    │     AB     ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │  A, A, A   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║   #4    │ AAA   │    2    │   AA, A    ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    3    │    AAA     ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │  A, A, B   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    2    │   AA, B    ║
║   #5    │ AAB   ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    3    │   AB, A    ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    4    │    AAB     ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │  A, B, C   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    2    │   AB, C    ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║   #6    │ ABC   │    3    │   AC, B    ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    4    │   BC, A    ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    5    │    ABC     ║
╠═════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║         │       │    1    │ A, B, C, D ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    2    │   AB, CD   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    3    │   AC, BD   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    4    │   BC, AD   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    5    │  A, BC, D  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    6    │  B, AC, D  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    7    │  C, AB, D  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║   #7    │ ABCD  │    8    │  A, CD, B  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │    9    │  A, BD, C  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   10    │  B, AD, C  ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   11    │   ABC, D   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   12    │   BCD, A   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   13    │   CDA, B   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   14    │   DAB, C   ║
║         │       ├─────────┼────────────╢
║         │       │   15    │    ABCD    ║
╚═════════╧═══════╧═════════╧════════════╝
```

Comment: What is the winning criterion of this challenge? Code-golf? Also the current explanation seems more complicated as it needs to be. Only after seeing the examples it became clear that you are asking for [set partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8691/56433

Answer (score 0):

## Show me your core

On many 8-bit machines, it is relatively easy to output the entire core syntax of the built-in language, as everything required is in ROM and most 8-bit machines allow you to `PEEK` at each location therein, or otherwise easily access the ROM contents.

Here's the complete syntax for a Sinclair ZX81 or Timex TS1000/1500 machine as an example:

```
 1 PRINT CHR$ 64;CHR$ 65;CHR$ 66;CHR$ 193;CHR$ 193;
 2 FOR I=196 TO 255
 3 PRINT CHR$ I;
 4 NEXT I
```

Is it as easy to output the core or standard syntax to a screen, console, or window in modern-days languages? How best would I word such a question? And would this make a good challenge?

Comment: What is the "core"? ......

Comment: Core syntax, i.e., non-extended PHP, such as stdClass is in the PHP core. Either the question is too ambiguous, or I don't know modern-days programming speak well enough to ask it.

Comment: More precisely, `PDOException("blah", 0x00);` would not be `core` in PHP even though it extends the standard `Exception` because the PDO extension needs to be switched on in your `php.ini` file; `throw` and `new` obviously would be as far as I'm able to work out

Comment: I don't know PHP so I don't understand that explanation.

Comment: I only really understand PHP and some 8-bit hl languages and some assembly. Let's try this... if you don't `<include xxx.h>` in C (where `xxx` is the header or whatever), what are you left with? Is that even possible.

Comment: [Actually GCC let the program pass with a lot of warnings.](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ1OhmqugtKRYQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSdOaq/b/fwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Some [similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5131/42963) and [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75899/42963) challenges showing that this type of challenge has a lot of difficulty in getting it exactly correct.

Comment: Yes there is a lot of difficulty on modern-days tech stacks and such; on 8-bit machines, it's much easier as you only need to find the bit of ROM that holds the syntax and you're half-way there.

Answer (score 0):

## Sight Matrix

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

---

> I haven't seen this done anywhere yet after a couple of searches, so I might as well post this anyways. If you see this done somewhere else, please tell me and I will delete this post.

### The Story

You are a two meter tall sniper fighting in a war-torn area. Your teams have just beaten back the enemy, but the guerillas have an annoying habit of hiding out of sight and waiting patiently to take your unit by surprise, often inflicting heavy casualties. You have been tasked with dealing with these guerillas as a sentry.

### The Task

#### Summary

Write a program that, when given a n x n 2D matrix of heights (in meters), outputs a n x n 2D binary matrix with ones being areas that you can see and zeroes being areas that you cannot see.

#### Input Format

The input will be a two-dimensional array of heights and two numbers signifying where you are standing.

#### Output Format

The output will be a two-dimensional array of ones and zeroes: ones where you can see and zeroes where you can't see.

#### Sample input/output

Input:

> `[[120,87,89,93,121],
>   [120,91,83,91,114],
>   [118,121,90,93,97],
>   [124,129,115,120,101],
>   [117,140,138,124,99]]
>   0
>   0`

Output:

> `[[1,1,1,1,1],
>   [1,1,1,1,1],
>   [1,1,1,1,1],
>   [0,0,1,1,1],
>   [0,0,0,0,1]]`

Hint:

> Last time I checked, people's eyes were on their head. Put that into account when you are writing your code.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply.

Note: this is my first foray into code-golf stackexchange. Please tell me how to improve this or things that I need to add to this answer.

Comment: There have been various questions on line of sight, but right now I think this question would be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" before there was consensus on which was the closest dupe. What are the rules for visibility? You've given my height, but I'm not sure whether it's relevant. You haven't said whether the guerrillas (note: double *r*) have a height, nor how the terrain is modelled, nor what point in the square I need to see for the square to count as visible.

Comment: May the input be 1-indexed?

Answer (score 0):

## Output One More than Int Max  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Your job is to create a program or function that will output a whole number (with no trailing decimal point) that is 1 greater than the max number an integer can hold for the language; more or less this:

```
MAX_INT + 1
```

You are not allowed to use Strings in your solution. Any other type may be used.

Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Note: I know this might be impossible in some languages. I have verified that it is possible in at least one (un-disclosed) language.

---

### Notes on this puzzle

I posted this puzzle recently [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151495/output-one-more-then-int-max) and it promptly got closed and deleted (oops). Thankfully, @WheatWizard was kind enough to explain what some of the confusion was. Here where his comments:

> I've voted to close this question as unclear. There are a couple of
>   things I find especially unclear, 1) I'm not sure what "the max number
>   an integer can hold for the language" means, it definitely needs a
>   more concrete definition. It seems to presuppose some bounded
>   "integer" type in the language. All the existing answers seem to
>   suppose that long (or equivalent) is not this integer type but that is
>   not at all clear from the question.
>
> 2) The requirement "You are not allowed to use strings in your
>   solution" is neither clear nor enforceable. Without a rigorous
>   definition of string there is no way to determine what is a string or
>   not. For example Prolog has a type called "String" but all real string
>   manipulation is actually done on lists of char codes. Are those
>   strings? Prolog also has atoms which behave a lot like strings in many
>   ways, (and act like integers in others) are they strings?
>
> The main thing I would want to see before retracting my close
>   vote/voting to reopen is clear definitions of the terms in question.
>   To be clear that is a very tall order. These terms are not going to be
>   easy to define, let alone define well. I would recommend temporarily
>   moving this question to the sandbox so that you can workshop it a bit.

@Xcali said the following:

> To follow on @WheatWizard's comment, what about languages where
>   there's really no type to a variable. For example, in Perl, any single
>   value may be treated as a string or a number at any time

And @Adám:

> @CalebKleveter I think you can fix your challenge by removing the
>   prohibition on strings and requiring documentation and/or additional
>   supporting code showing that the produced number cannot be held as any
>   type of integer. Do you want me to edit your post accordingly?

Are there any suggestions on how we could define the things pointed out in these comments? Are there any other issues that should be resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to define such things such that it can applies to all languages. You may want to limit the challenge to specific languages, but that will disallow many languages to compete, and some person will get annoyed when their languages can't be used, they may downvote the question. / [Original challenge link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151495/output-one-more-then-int-max).

Answer (score 0):

**Als pr Yrck, I knw hm Hrtio**

Here is a link to a text file containing the script for Shakespeare's Hamlet.<sup>[to do: provide such a text file, or think of another freely available text input that leads to a wittier title.]</sup>

Your task is to write a program that will compress this text, and another that will decompress it to return exactly the original file. Your score is given by `C + D + 0.5*F`, where `C` is the size of your compression program, `D` is the size of your decompression program, and `F` is the size of the file that your compression program generates, all measured in bytes. The smallest score wins.

**Further particulars**

Your compression program should take `hamlet.txt` as input and produce a single file as output, which is to be given as input to your decompression program. You should make sure that the resulting output from your decompression program is identical to the original `hamlet.txt` file, e.g.

```
> myCompressor hamlet.txt > compressed
> myDecompressor compressed > output.txt
> diff hamlet.txt output.txt
[no output from diff command means they are identical]
```

Your programs' only purpose is to compress and decompress the `hamlet.txt` file - their behaviour on any other input is not part of the challenge. It's fine, for example, if the decompressor always outputs the text of Hamlet regardless of the original input, or if the compressor crashes on any input besides `hamlet.txt`.

Input and output can be by file I/O or STDIN/STDOUT or any other reasonable method, but the compressor and decompressor should be full programs. They need not be written in the same language.

Your compressor and decompressor must each be completely self-contained. Each must consist of a single file, and that file must be the source code for a programming language as defined [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). With the exception of importing libraries, your compressor and decompressor must not open any other files besides their input.

The compressed file may be a text file or a binary file - the only thing that matters is its size in bytes. No information may be transmitted from the compressor to the decompressor by any means other than the content of this file.

You may not use any libraries or built-ins that implement data compression algorithms, such as `gzip` or `bz2`, or their corresponding decompression algorithms. This restriction only applies to "off the shelf" implementations - you can use any algorithm you like if you implement it yourself. For details on what counts as a data compression algorithm, see note 1.

If for some reason your language or libraries include a feature that outputs some or all of the text of Hamlet, you may not use that feature.

Although it's not part of the challenge, you are encouraged to explain/demonstrate what happens when your compressor is given some other input besides `hamlet.txt`, especially if it does something interesting such as produce a garbled Shakespearean version of the input text.

<sub>**Note 1:** For the purpose of this challenge, a data compression algorithm is anything listed in Wikipedia's [Category:Lossless Compression Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lossless_compression_algorithms) or [Category:Lossy Compression Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lossy_compression_algorithms), or any of their subcategories. Note that these lists can change over time, and if Wikipedia's editors will allow a new item to be added then that will count as a compression algorithm, even if that happens after an answer using it is posted. This is to prevent the use of obscure algorithms that are not yet listed on Wikipedia. Editing Wikipedia to get around the restriction on off-the-shelf compression is not allowed.</sub>

<sub>This rule is intended to prevent the use of existing algorithms while allowing all other language features and built-ins. It may be the case that some items on the Wikipedia list are overly broad and end up banning common language features. If this is the case I will add exceptions on a case-by-case basis. This will only be used to permit things that would otherwise be banned, so it won't invalidate existing answers.</sub>

---

***Sandbox note:*** the really tricky thing here is how to prevent trivial solutions that just wrap an existing compression algorithm, without also banning common language features. The above Wikipedia-based definition of a compression algorithm is a bit experimental and I'd welcome feedback on it. My intention is to prevent trivial solutions that just wrap an existing implementation of a compression algorithm, while allowing pretty much anything else.

*Another possible approach is simply to allow anything and hope that answers specialised to the input can achieve better scores. That's effectively what I did in [Paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code), but in the end I wish I hadn't, because it turned out that (so far at least) even really clever solutions based on neural nets and genetic algorithms can't come close to the off-the-shelf BPG algorithm. That's the sort of situation I want to avoid for this challenge.*

Comment: Would [compressor](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g////JRmpCsXJRZkFJQpp@UUKwRmJ2anFBamJRanqxQoeibk5qSUA), [decompressor](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCcxKFwxoEzQMSg4bm@xqRKxqzhu6ThuIR9w5DCu///) be acceptable? (only for illustration purposes)

Comment: @user202729 I don't speak Jelly, but assuming it's not using any built-in compression, that would be fine. (It even says so already in the rules: "It's fine, for example, if the decompressor always outputs the text of Hamlet regardless of the original input".) The thing is that a solution of that form doesn't take any advantage of the discounted scoring for the compressed file, so it would very likely not be optimal. So while it's allowed, it would probably not win.

Comment: Correct, if the text is sufficiently long. The `“...»` is Jelly string encoding codec using base decompression and some [dictionary](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/dictionary.py) lookup.

Comment: @user202729 then it would be fine. (I'm fairly certain the script for Hamlet is long enough - if it isn't, that would be an interesting surprise.)

Comment: @user202729 Though actually, I guess by the letter of what I wrote, it wouldn't be fine, because Jelly's dictionary lookup is presumably explicitly intended as a way to compress text. That's not what I intended the rule to mean. This is pretty tricky - I want to disallow trivial things like just wrapping a bz2 compressor, while permitting pretty much anything else. It doesn't seem easy to do that in a way that avoids loopholes. (Comments on this are welcome from anyone.)

Comment: You can't disallow "trivial" things, only discourage them. That's not really a problem - the real problem is they get more upvotes than they deserves, and solutions which the OP actually put effort in writing get less upvotes.

Comment: @user202729 I can't disallow trivial things in general, but I can write the rules in such a way that specific types of trivial solution are not permitted. If I had disallowed built-in compression in [paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) then it would have been a much better challenge (albeit possibly less epic in the long run, since the non-trivial answers made a good effort at keeping up with the trivial ones). Basically I don't want the winning answer to just be a shell script that runs bzip on its input.

Comment: Anyway I've changed the wording of the rule - I'm not sure if the new version will work but we'll see if people have comments.

Comment: Instead of stating something like "*If for some reason your language or libraries include a feature that outputs some or all of the text of Hamlet, you may not use that feature.*" you could actually require the program to work for any input and only use Hamlet to get the scoring, this would elegantly close up that loophole but I'm sure people will find a way around this.. As you noted yourself this is a difficult task to solve.

Comment: @BruceForte I think I prefer the direct approach for that point. If I ask it to work for other inputs I open up the quagmire of trying to define what that should mean and how to test for it. However that's achieved I would likely still need the "if for some reason" rule, because there would probably still be ways to take advantage of a built-in database of Shakespeare plays if some language out there happens to include one. I think banning Shakespeare built-ins is unproblematic - my problem is more how to ban bz2 and the like without accidentally also banning common language features.

Comment: "in the end I wish I hadn't" ... Why? What's the difference?

Comment: @user202729 it would have been a better challenge. The best scoring answers would have been the cleverest ones that took the most effort, and there would be more motivation for people to continue doing cleverer things to beat the lowest score. If that doesn't seem desirable to you then fair enough, but it's what my taste is and it's the kind of challenge I want to design.

Comment: How can you be so sure (without testing it)? bz2 developers definitely put a lot of efforts into writing their lossy image compression algorithms, so they may win. Not to mention that their code are not bytecount-limited.

Comment: @user202729 I'm not sure what you mean. If you're referring to the Starry Night challenge I can be sure because I have tested it. Just look at the existing answers - some are really really nontrivial and use genetic algorithms, deep neural networks and other clever techniques, whereas others simply wrap an image in BPG or FLIF format and call an existing function to decompress it. There is some golfing and file type knowledge involved in this, but it's trivial compared to the other type of answer. Unfortunately the latter type *did* win, and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid this time.

Comment: (The clever answers on Starry Night exist in large part because I offered a series of bounties to answers that passed various milestones without using built-in compression. I could do that again this time, but I have only 2100 rep to give away, and in any case it's much more elegant if the challenge provides that motivation by itself.)

Comment: Hm... you mean that if you generalize the starry night challenge the neural network will win over bz2? Really? I still feel skeptical about it. But anyway, [about this Hamlet challenge] what about people writing their own compression algorithm, but make it a Python library (assume they have permission) and then the actual code only import it? Will that be allowed? (I think no, but, we no longer forbid languages postdate the challenge if they are not challenge-specific)

Comment: @user202729 no, that's not what I mean at all - I think we've missed each others' meaning at some point above, I'm not sure where. Regarding writing a new Python library for a challenge, no, that would not be allowed on any PPCG challenge as far as I know. (If it doesn't come under one of the standard loopholes it should do.)

Comment: I [just asked this on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42029932#42029932).

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14351/66833); the main challenge isn't is building a compressor, the difference being scoring differences.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks, it has some similarities but is definitely not a duplicate. (That challenge is trying to make a general compressor while this one is specialised to a particular input. Additionally, that challenge has a mistake that makes it impossible unless I misunderstood it - I've commented there for why.)

Comment: IMHO, I don't think this is a good challenge. It's generally asking to compress and decompress a particular byte stream, but have undefined behavior on anything else. This could lead to answers such as what user202729 linked [above](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14497#comment52566_14497). Generalizing the challenge would instead make it a dupe of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58523/41024).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer the scoring system has been carefully worked out to make solutions of that form, and other trivial solutions, sub-optimal, so that they won't be competitive.

Comment: @Nathaniel Where is the scoring system?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `C + D + 0.5*F`, where `C` is the size of your compression program, `D` is the size of your decompression program, and `F` is the size of the file that your compression program generates, all measured in bytes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer you get a 50% discount for data that your compressor can extract and store in the compressed file, so solutions that store all the output in the decompressor are unlikely to be competitive.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bonuses are discouraged.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it's not a bonus in that sense.

Comment: @Nathaniel Let's say that `C` is 1 byte, `F` is 0 bytes, and `D` is 1000 bytes (Jelly dictionary compression). In this case, the score would be 1001, and that looks pretty competitive to me.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer well let's say `C` is 50 bytes, `F` is 1000 bytes (Jelly dictionary compression), and `D` is 50 bytes. Then the score would be 600. Yours doesn't look so competitive any more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71174/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-nathaniel).

Answer (score 0):

### Your Task:

#### To create a piece of code that takes in an input, and outputs ASCII art, which is encoded in the input string.

It seems unclear, but you are basically creating your own programming language that takes a piece of code in a syntax that you create, and then writing a code that takes that input, and turns it into ASCII art.

---

### Example:

A simple example would be an input that runs through a line of input code with the syntax:

```
0 : An empty space
1 : A space that is occupied
2 : A newline character
```

**I:**

```
01010210101201010210101201010
```

**O:**

```
 The '|' character is just to show the matrix

| # # |
|# # #|
| # # |
|# # #|
| # # |
```

**I:**

```
11112000121111210002111122 // Shows a 2
11112100121001210012111122 // Shows a 0
0120120120120122 // Shows a 1
11112100121111210012111122 // Shows an 8
```

**O:**

```
####   
   # 
#### 
#  
#### 

####
#  #
#  #
#  #
####

 #
 #
 #
 #
 #

####
#  #
####
#  #
####
```

The code would read through the letters one by one and print out the characters, or create a newline character as expected.

---

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the code with the fewest bytes wins!

Comment: [Jelly, 0 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwI1CspAWMNVA6KUgTR2PgA) - is that what you meant?

Comment: This is currently very unclear. As far as I see, you say we need to write code which decodes some input string to some output string. But what exactly is the decoding? Your 0,1,2 substitution seems to be an example only.

Comment: I think this would be pretty much trivial in most languages. Expect a lot of 2-3 byte answers. Might want to make it a bit more complex

Answer (score 0):

## Stem and Leaf

A stem-and-leaf plot is a way to represent data and visualizing distribution. Usually the data is grouped in step of 10, with the last digit as "leafs" in ascending order, and the remaining digits as "stem". The steam and leafs are separated with a vertical line, with stem on the left and leafs on the right.

### Challenge

Make a program or function which takes a list of non-negative integers as input, and outputs the corresponding stem-and-leaf plot.

### Example Input and Outputs

#### Example 1:

Input: 
`10 2 15 4 2 24 18 17 24 24 25 15 18 22 17 23 24 33 19 28 28 28 26 32 25 27 37 28 41 38 38 30 35 30 41 45 40 40 37 33`

Output:

```
0|224           
1|05577889      
2|23444455678888
3|0023357788    
4|00115
```

#### Example 2:

Input:
`112 101 116 99 99 107 101 99 115 112 114 128 115 119 125 160 148 147 159 147 169 160 163 160 160 163 162 164 160 173 84 92`

Output:

```
 8|4
 9|2999       
10|117       
11|2245569   
12|58        
13|
14|778       
15|9         
16|0000023349
17|3
```

### Rules

- The input may be a list, an array, a space or comma delimited string or other appropriate representation containing raw data values.
- The vertical line of the output must be aligned.
- A leading or trailing newline, or trailing spaces for each line are accepted.
- Common loopholes applied.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the lowest-byte solution for each language wins!

Comment: [highly related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128019/67312), probable duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're a dishonorable scientist trying to prove that getting heads on a coin flip actually has about 70% probability when flipped 100 times.  The trick is, you're going to flip the coin an arbitrarily large number of times (say, a million) and select the slice of 100 flips that contains the most number of heads.  As input, take the number of total trials to do, and as output, return the number of heads contained within the most favorable contiguous slice of 100.

Comment: Please "Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it.". If you post the challenge like this you will get a lot of problems.

Comment: (question title, winning criteria, tags, example input/output, everything you didn't have)

Comment: I like the idea, but the correctness of the answer is a little hard to verify. Perhaps you should require the answer writers to explicitly indicate how the program does the required job, unless it's really obvious from the code. For example, someone may directly draw a value from the resulting distribution without actually generating the total number of trials. That should be acceptable, as long as the writer justifies that their approach is correct, that is, gives the exact required distribution for the output

Answer (score 0):

## Find a Path of Similar Proportions!

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Given a point on a square lattice, find the shortest path (by jumps) from the origin to that point, following these rules:

- You are allowed to make any number of jumps containing any number of steps along the grid lines to another lattice point. These jumps must be along the grid lines and have an integer length.
- Each jump **must** contain one step more or be one step shorter than the step before it. (This is where the "similar proportions" comes into play. Name change pending?)
- The first step can have any length.

As an example, here is how one possible way one might travel from A(0,0) to B(5,5) under these rules:

```
A
|
|
|
1----2
     B
     |
     |
     3
```

The numbers indicate which steps are taken. Note that this solution backtracks, moving to (5,8) before partially retracing its path to get to its destination. This solution takes four jumps and is therefore optimal.

Here is a diagram of the number of jumps required for the shortest (or is it?) path to any other point with both integer coordinates below or equal to 10. Note the symmetry around (x,x). I don't know if my solution for (7,10) is optimal.

```
  | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
--------------------------------------
0 | 0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1 | 1  3  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
2 | 1  2  3  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
3 | 1  3  2  3  2  3  3  3  3  3  4
4 | 1  3  3  2  4  2  3  3  3  3  3
5 | 1  3  3  3  2  4  2  3  3  3  3
6 | 1  3  3  3  3  2  4  2  4  3  3
7 | 1  3  3  3  3  3  2  4  2  4  5?
8 | 1  3  3  3  3  3  4  2  4  2  4
9 | 1  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  2  4  2
10| 1  3  3  4  3  3  3  5? 4  2  4
```

### The actual actual task

Your task is to continue the table for points with coordinates as large as (127,127).

Your submission should be a program which prints valid paths for all points whose two coordinates lie between 0 and an inputted positive integer inclusively, or a function, which, given any pair of positive integers, outputs a valid path to the point specified by these coordinates.

A valid output path is an array or list (or other comparable datatype) which uniquely represents a valid sequence of jumps that can be used to reach the specified point and which makes it as easy as possible to find the number of jumps required.

Example possible ways for the example path given above:

```
[["d", 4], ["r", 5], ["d", 4], ["u", 3]] // using chars to represent direction
[[0, 4], [5, 0], [0, 4], [0, -3]] // direction vectors
[0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0, -3] // As above, in just one list. len()/2
```

### Scoring

Your submission will be scored by the sum of your solution's bytecount and the sum of all jump counts for all paths it outputs for reaching any point between (0,0) and (127,127), inclusively. Smallest score wins, standard rules and loopholes apply, etc...

### Example response (Python 3):

```
def c(a,b):
    d,e,g=[[a,0]],a+1,0
    while not g==b:
        d.append([0,e])
        e,g=-e+1,g+e
    return d
```

This extremely simple and naive piece of Python code achieves a score of 92 (program length) + 1406272 (for the path part) = 1406364, as verified here - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoMgEEXXcIpZQpw22G6aJpzEuEAZEWNGQjBNT0@1XXb7/nv56V3mje@1eppgVA4H/ZTCI2GwXefQ9D26pkUjxWuOKwFvBYK1w2EJf3UpEXvVGaReH@TMLnT4oSEpMpU9M/g6bjsXsGCknLYMESJDdhxItbfHeXjS5Y@KX9dYWInVqCIuWkuZcuSivpuuHw)

### More?

- missing tags?
- clarifications?
- Table is incorrect?

Please respond.

Answer (score 0):

### Unicode reversible programs

The goal is to make a program that includes unicode formatting characters that when executed as-is generates a OEIS sequence, and when copied as its rendered* and executed, returns a different sequence.

- The renderer is one that properly reacts to unicode formatting. For example with RLO the text should be reverted. (Its stored as "\u202etest" but renders as "tset"

This is will be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the answer with less bytes wins.

Comment: What do you mean by "*copied as its rendered and executed*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean that for example the text "\u202e hello" is rendered as "olleh " because U+202E is a unicode control character that reverses text (when rendered)

Comment: Define it objectively. How browsers/text editors handle copy-paste are implementation-defined. (which browsers/text editors, which exact ways to copy-paste, put the pointer on which pixel of the screen, etc.)

Comment: U+202E is not a Unicode control character: the Unicode control characters are the ranges U+0000 to U+001F  and U+007F to U+009F.

Comment: Also: this question talks about characters and bytes but it doesn't address the relationship between them, which is a minefield. What about languages which don't use UTF-8 or UTF-16 for their source? What about languages which use either according to a command-line flag: can the transformed program change the state of that flag?

Comment: @PeterTaylor languages that dont use utf-8 it in their source can use a escaped form such as (0xe2 0x80 0xae). Also thanks for pointing that its actually a formatting character (not control)

Comment: So basically split on the unicode char and reverse all that's after it? Possibly multiple times? Doesn't sound too interesting.

Comment: "for example"? Questions (challenges) need to be self-included. List all of them please.

Answer (score 0):

## Non-true, non-false JS boolean

Array prototype isn't redefined, input hasn't getters

```
function magic(input){
  let result = [];
  if(input.boolean != true){result.push("non-true");}
  if(input.boolean != false){result.push("non-false");}
  result.push(input);
  return result.join("\n");
}
```

returns

```
non-true
non-false
{"boolean": true}
```

What is passed to `magic` function?

Based on real problem :) I spent 30 minutes on this puzzle

Comment: This site is for programming contests, not pure programming puzzles. Thanks for using the sandbox, anyway.

Comment: Contrary to what user202729 states, Programming Puzzles are [on-topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5585/42963) on this site. This challenge could use a little cleanup to make it a better fit here (for example, what language is this?), but this challenge is indeed allowed here.

Comment: ... someone said that I'm wrong. Anyway people definitely doesn't like this.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork this is JS

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков what JS version is this? `in` is a keyword, and can't be a variable name.

Comment: @dzaima Good point. Last time I check on TIO the object `{boolean: true}` doesn't have `"` around and it caused a syntax error. I forgot about `in` so just try to rename it and it worked...

Comment: "Programming Puzzle" is in the name of the site @user202729

Comment: @dylnan [But...](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/is-the-name-of-the-community-correct)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork is correct.  We *do* allow programming puzzles.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Then just upvote the comment.

Comment: Many many things in the past, including but not limited to, [tag:code-trolling], [tag:underhanded], non-observable behavior, etc. are off-topic or heavily-discouraged nowadays. Be careful.

Comment: @user202729 I did upvote.  I just wanted to make sure it was extra clear to the OP.  Furthermore, this challenge doesn't fit *any* of those tags, because its not asking for trolling/underhanded/non-observable code.  You could argue that the code in the challenge fits those tags, but that's not what we care about.

Comment: I don't believe that `console` is part of any JS spec. This presumably only works in certain contexts, and the question should specify what they are. Otherwise the task devolves into [tag:code-trolling] by defining a suitable `console`. It's already borderline IMO.

Comment: @dzaima sorry, fixed this. Now input variable is `input`

Comment: @PeterTaylor changed `console.log` to array with return to fit this case. Also object hasn't getters, its real-life problem

Comment: 01) If this isn't an original challenge, you should provide attribution. 02) This would probably fit better as a [tag:tips] question than a challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy this isn't tip for golfing and original flavour of puzzle saved. I dealed with it, when coded recaptha for site

Comment: OK, so, in that case you may want to work on the wording of the challenge before posting it to Main because, right now, it reads as though you've come across this challenge elsewhere, spent half an hour trying to solve and are now looking for help doing so. Also, just so you know, restricted language challenges rarely go down well here.

Comment: [Boring problem here](https://tio.run/##dY9NDoIwEIX3nGLshnYBB7DhJOqi1oIldYb0xw3h7BUpJi50@7358t6M6qmC9naKDdLN5Nwn1NESwkMNVnOLU4pirgCcieBNSC5CB6eLXJHtS95eiZxRCIcOok9GzOWwnVK4c4aEzRszIZc/Vq9c@KVtfPe@wzJLbjQmj59wJIucnXFVqqXShGGtaB0NvLxTz2xvZcdt6lILIXN@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

Tags: Codegolf

Title: evil detection

When given any (you may choose the format and you should assume integer input) input, the output should be true if the input is a palindrome and false if not (or 1/0 or any equivalent).

To make it (a lot) harder, your code must work with a result that fulfills the challenge **inverted** if read backwards. So for a palindrome input, forward gives true, backwards false.

Example:

If your code is "abc12" and the input is 1221, your code should produce true-ish and "21cba" (your code read backwards) should produce false-ish.

Bonus if you think that's to easy: produce false if and only if the input is 666 forward and true backwards.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110582/58974)

Comment: First, I want to say thanks for using the sandbox! Also, I do think you could go somewhere with this idea that doesn't make it a duplicate. Your idea is marginally different, in that it only requires the code to behave the same forward and backwards, rather than actually be a palindrome. While I think for palindromes it will almost always be best to have a palindrome, perhaps you can think of a different pattern that makes it more interesting? I'll let you know if I think of anything.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, I don't think the fact that the code need not be palindromic is enough to make this not be a dupe; many of the solutions to the challenge above would also be the optimal solution here. Maybe if this one required that the code *not* be a palindrome and also required that it output a different pair of consistent and distinct values when run in reverse, it might be enough to differentiate it?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'll have a look at the other answers, but I agree that allowing the code to be semi-palindromic is not enough (unless the other answers are all extremely long, I haven't looked yet). I'm thinking about making the code required to not be symmetric, but haven't figured out what to do with the input to make it fit

Comment: @Shaggy That seems like a good start for changing it. For the record, I definitely think that as it was when I posted it was a duplicate, I just thought there was something good in this challenge and I didn't want it to just be discarded! The unfortunate thing about just requiring non symmetry is that comments/newlines could often just be added at the end without much cost, but I do think there is a good challenge here, somewhere.

Comment: @fryamtheeggman how about this?

Comment: I think the problem with this is that while some of the answers to the other question will no longer work, some are still usable here with only a slight modification, so I don't think this will cut it.

Comment: @Fryamtheeggman and if I make the bonus question mandatory? But I'll think some more

Answer (score 0):

## Chiasmus Indenter

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Chiasmus is a [literary form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus) that is similar to palindromes. Some ideas are presented and then presented again in reverse order, often phrased differently.

Natural language processing is hard, so I'll be using a more computer-friendly definition. A chiasmic string is made up of a series of substrings that are repeated in reverse order in the second half of a string. Formally:

- If `a` is some non-empty string, then `aa` is chiasmic.
- If `C` is chiasmic and `a` is some string, then `aCa` is also chiasmic. Note that this applies recursively, thus `abCba` is chiasmic if `C` is also chiasmic and `a` and `b` are non-empty strings.

For example, `batbat` is chiasmic, as are `glassbottlebottleglass` and `AliceBobCharlieCharlieBobAlice`. All even-length palindromes are chiasmic, being made up of many length-1 strings.

Note that the empty string is not a chiasmus.

## The Challenge

We're programmers, so we like nice indentation. Your goal is to take chiasmic strings and indent them so that each matching substring is at the same level of indentation. For example, `cheesepizzawithanchoviesanchovieswithpizzacheese` would be indented like so:

```
cheese
    pizza
        with
            anchovies
            anchovies
        with
    pizza
cheese
```

For base case chiasms (i.e. 2 repetitions of a string), no indentation is necessary, but the substrings should still be on separate lines. Thus, `gumgum` would be indented:

```
gum
gum
```

In order for there to be only one canonical output for each chiasmus, if it is possible to indent at more than one place, indent in a way such that the `a` substrings for the form `aCa` are as long as possible (applied recursively for each `C` until the `aa` base case is reached). For example, `catdogcatdogdogcatdogcat` should be indented like this:

```
catdogcat
    dog
    dog
catdogcat
```

Not like this:

```
cat
    dog
        cat
            dog
            dog
        cat
    dog
cat
```

Also not like this:

```
cat
    dogcatdog
    dogcatdog
cat
```

The behavior of indenting a non-chiasmus is undefined.

## Rules

- Indentation can use any amount of whitespace of any kind, so long as it is consistent (e.g. do not mix tabs and spaces). Lines may either be output as a list/array/whatever or a newline-separated string.
- You may assume that the input is a chiasmus that contains only alphanumeric characters.
- As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest submission wins.

Comment: May indentation be done with a `\t` character?

Comment: I probably should do that since it saves 2 characters and is purely cosmetic.

Comment: "Longest possible substrings" still leaves some room for ambiguity.  What's the canonical output for `ababbaba`?

Comment: `aba` `b` `b` `aba`. I see how it can be indented as `a` `bab` `bab` `a`, though.

Comment: I kept waiting for a `glassbottlebottleglass` test case!

Comment: @Shaggy Wish granted.

Comment: I don't understand the `catdogcatdogdogcatdogcat` example. It seems to me to directly contradict the rule it's supposed to be illustrating.

Comment: @PeterTaylor how so?

Comment: On review, I agree that "*directly contradict*" is overstating it. But the minimalist indentation still doesn't fit the rest of the question. The stated grammar is pointless: the derivation `aCa` is only permitted for *extremely* limited values of `C` (strings of the form `bb` such that there aren't `c` and `d` satisfying `ab = cd` and `|c| > |a|`). The statement "*indent in such a way that the lowest **levels** of indentation have the longest strings possible*" (my emphasis) makes no sense, because there is at most one level of indentation (or two if you count "unindented" as the first).

Comment: And the statement "*All even-length palindromes are chiasmic, being made up of many length-1 strings*" is not true, because the canonicalisation forces it to be made up of one repeated length-1 string and an outer layer of a repeated length-(n-2)/2 string.

Comment: The `aCa` form is recursive. Maybe I should make that clearer with the examples.

Comment: I would suggest dropping the requirement to produce an error on non-chiasmal(?) input, and instead just guarantee that the input will be a chiasmus. This changes it from two challenges (detect whether the input is a chiasmus, and then indent it if it is) to one (indent a chiasmus). Just my opinion though.

Comment: [Slightly related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154808/58974)

Comment: @Shaggy Well yeah it's related. I created that challenge and it was a direct inspiration for this one.

Answer (score 0):

### Build a Brainfuck transpiler

Your job is to build a program that transpiles valid brainfuck to a language (not brainfuck!) of your choice.

You are not required to handle cases where the program is invalid (mismatched [ ]s), or contains characters that are not +-<>[],. but all other cases must be handled.

Size limits on your input or output are fine as long as they are imposed by computer restrictions, like RAM.

The programming language you transpile *to* is covered under the "What defines a programming language" rules, and must have been created before this challange.

In extension to not transpiling to brainfuck (cheater!) you can't use a brainfuck derivative or trival brainfuck substitution as the transpiled to language either.

#### Scoring

Programs will be scored with the average ratio of bytes in the input brainfuck program to the output transpiled result, as based on the examples.

### Meta questions

This is a rough draft!
What tags should be associated with this?
How can I improve the scoring system?
What examples should I use to keep the scoring fair, but prevent obvious tricks?
What loopholes are there in this rough draft that I need to patch?

This entire thing will be reorganized when I get enough info to make a better writeup.

Comment: I'd tag it with [tag:code-challenge] and [tag:brainfuck]. Once you post the examples the scoring system seems to be fine, the major problem would be hardcoding but [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/48198) is a standard loophole, so this should be fine. Also you should probably consider adding a non-terminating example. About preventing brainfuck derivatives: I'm not sure if this is well-defined enough, maybe others have some ideas?

Comment: @BMO About hardcoding: Just hide the official test cases. You don't need to prevent BF derivative, they would just be boring (and downvoted most likely). Also it's very hard to define them (What about 2D BF? What about Unary? What about Random BF / self-modifying BF?)

Comment: Also, BF is too unclear as a language specification. (is memory wrapping or infinite to one end or infinity to both ends? Are values positive/negative/modulo 256? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

### Self-removing executable (retracted: [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19355/a-program-that-deletes-itself))

Comment: I don't like the restriction, it makes it easier for you to test (I guess that's the point of it?), but it prevents me (and many others) from competing. Saying it must handle "long and unusual characters" is underspecified. You can say that the program must be able to handle _any valid filename_, in the chosen operating system. The example code is already very short, so it doesn't leave much room for golfing, with all the restrictions in place.

Comment: Which restriction? Shall it be centered around per-language leaderboard then?

Comment: Always per-language. I guess t's not all restrictions, but all the Linux-specific stuff. Keep in mind that these are only my opinions though, others might disagree.

Comment: It _could_ be a good idea to have it Linux specific, but the example code is already so short that it leaves very little room for creativity.

Comment: Dupe: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19355/a-program-that-deletes-itself ?

Answer (score 0):

## Navigate my Taxi

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Introduction

[Taxi](http://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/) is an esoteric programming language simulating a taxi. You can pick up passengers (values) and drop them at special places to modify them. For example, [this program](https://tio.run/##tVJLDoIwEN1zijkAIfGzYqkLVkYTuUDFoUxsWtKWKKfH8hMFYmRh0knnk/dm@jqWPaiqIgXWnQzhpIyFY5pSgiHc0QUrZwJT6zeeJp51bp0MvBMltyIHBjkzBiVHDVyR5DVh7Ah37IIiJZOhLgOvbTTOh2BUYbO5Vt8b7MtEKIk9bxeGIJWe0LXeWl5/IT4UwlIuKGGWlISzbe4BI5UTSy9BthPOV6fvf43pw9YV/iP1or8cLUfPP9mZOek7wQdE7LYOIqYZ/0CMBnoHV9XmCQ) squares the input. The places are all in Townsburg:

[image: Map of Townsburg]

To travel from one place to another, you have to tell your taxi where to go:

```
Go to the Post Office: west 1st left, 1st right, 1st left.
```

And you need gas to drive, your car gets 18 miles per gallon. So it's best to find the shortest possible way between two places. That leads me to ...

### The Challenge

#### Input

You get an incomplete Taxi program, consisting of the following statements:

- `Pickup a[nother] passenger going to [the] <place>.`: Pickup a passenger, you may ignore it for this challenge
- `"<string>" is waiting at [the] Writer's Depot.` / `<number> is waiting at [the]
  Starchild Numerology.`: Create passengers, you may ignore this, too
- `Go to [the] <place>.`: Go to a place, you have to add directions (see below)
- `[<label>]`: A label for jumping, you have to parse those to know where the taxi is. They don't do anything if passed. You can assume that you are in the same location, regardless of where you reach the label from.
- `Switch to plan "<label>".`: Unconditional jump, follow these to know where the taxi is
- `Switch to plan "<label>" if no one is waiting.`: Conditional jump, you have to support both ways

If the input program contains anything else, you may do anything you want (undefined behaviour).

#### Conversion

Following all jumping instructions, you have to add directions to the `Go to` commands. It has to be the shortest possible way (I want to save gas!)

Directions consist of a cardinal direction (`north`, `east`, `south`, `west` or `NESW`) and a comma-separated list of turns, consisting of a number (`1st 2nd 3rd` or `1 2 3`) and `left`/`L` or `right`/`R`.

Examples:

```
Go to the Post Office: west 1st left, 1st right, 1st left.
Go to Post Office: W 1 L, 1 R, 1 L.
Go to Tom's Trims: N.
```

The cardinal directions do have the following meanings (x<sub>start</sub> means x pos of the starting point, y<sub>end</sub> means y pos of the next corner/intersection/place):

- north: y<sub>start</sub> > y<sub>end</sub>
- south: y<sub>start</sub> < y<sub>end</sub>
- west: x<sub>start</sub> > x<sub>end</sub>
- east: x<sub>start</sub> < x<sub>end</sub>

(Coordinates from the top left corner)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/RYc3hxBV) is a list of all intersections/corners/places/streets, extracted from the interpreter.

Some additional info:

- The taxi starts at the Taxi Garage.
- If the taxi reaches the Taxi Garage, the program ends.
- If the program reaches its end and the taxi is not in the Taxi Garage, that's an error, so you'll have to add 'Go to the Taxi Garage: ...' at the end if it's missing.

#### Output

- Your program or function has to output a valid Taxi program ([online interpreter](https://tio.run/#Taxi)) or a list of instructions (which, when concatenated, form a valid Taxi program)
- You may use the long (north 1st left) or short (N 1 L) syntax.
- The ways chosen have to be the shortest possible (droven distance, i.e. sum of Euclidian distances between any two consecutive points on your way)
- If there are multiple equally long ways, you can use any of them

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/78123) are forbidden
- Your score is the number of bytes in your program
- Lowest score wins

#### Test Cases

*TODO*

> - Is any part of the specs confusing?
> - Should I not input a full program, but just start and destination?
> - Should I add the map in some format as an additional input?

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox, but I'm sorry that it's not very active. We [decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/winning-criteria-vs-valid-criteria) that "typical desktop computer" is not clear enough, so you should change it.

Comment: What is "shortest" measured in? Euclidean distance? What if there are multiple equally long paths?

Comment: @user202729 Edit: time is now on TIO, distance is sum of Euclidian distances between any two consecutive points on the way. I'm thinking about writing a program that calculates the distance

Comment: TIO is still not usable for time-related things. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/is-tio-acceptable-for-fastest-code-questions .

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the taxi will be in the same location regardless of how we reach a label?

Comment: @user202729 Ok, removed time limit

Comment: @Nitrodon finally, I got what you meant. Sure. Although theoretically, if both points lie on one street, one could do that ... (I would not recommend it)

Answer (score 0):

## Convert a number to (Name-To-Be-Specified)

(Name-To-Be-Specified) is a completely made up language. It uses a Senary (base 6) system of numbers with words for those numbers structured in a similar way to English.

**0 to 6**
Single digit numbers use a single word for each digit.

0 = "zeeroo"
1 = "nimbo"
2 = "feta"
3 = "tarumba"
4 = "ntamno"
5 = "waramaka"
(Any similarity to Kómnzo numbers are coincidental.)

**6 to 11**
The first set of two-digits numbers have special rules.

6 = "wi"
7 = "seeveen"
8 = "ayte"
9 = "tarumbawin"
10 = "ntamnowin"
11 = "waramakawin"

**12 to 35**
Multiples of 6 have the single digit word with a "wee" suffix.

12 = "fetawee"
18 = "tarambawee"
24 = "ntamnowee"
30 = "waramakawee"

Other numbers in this range are made by joining the word for the multiple of 6 with the word for single digit number, separated by a space. For example:
13 = "fetawee nimbo"
20 = "tarambawee feta"
27 = "ntamnowee taramba"
34 = "waramakawee ntamno"

**36 to 1295**
**1296 to 46655**
**46656 to 1679615**
**1679616 to 60466175**
(Since this is a sandbox, I'll leave these to-be-specified for now. Suffice to say I'll come up with words for each and consistent rules for joining them together and when you need the word "and".)

## Challenge

Write a program that takes an integer as input and outputs that number in (Name-To-Be-Specified) words as described above. Shortest code wins.

Comment: A language called [Golfish](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish) already exists >_<

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I believe you mean `Gol><>`

Comment: That's a programming language, not a spoken language. But fair point, if I graduate this to an actual question I'll pick a new name.

Comment: @Mego Well yeah but the repository name is Golfish...

Comment: Anyway, I'd advise referencing that you're not referring to Gol><> in any way. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Paintball Tournament

Inspired by [The Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock Tournament of Epicness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35079/the-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-tournament-of-epicness) as well as other King-of-the-hill challenges, I would like to propose a Paintball Tournament.

There is a game on my phone, called [Game Pigeon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gamepigeon/id1124197642?mt=8) that contains a paintball game. This paintball game is played by two players. The object of the game is to shoot your opponent **x** times before they shoot you **x** times.

#### Gameplay

The game is played in two sets of rounds. A moving round and a shooting round.

Both players, without their opponents knowledge, pick from three objects in front of them to hide behind.

```
                                (P1) X           X
                                     X           X (P2)
                                     X           X
```

Both players, without their opponents knowledge, choose which target across from them they would like to shoot at. After players decide which target to shoot at, players shoot at the targets chosen in unison, during which expose themselves from behind their target and are vulnerable to be hit.

Let's go through a small example. In the movement round, P1 has chosen to hide behind their left-most target. P2 has chosen to hide behind their middle target. In the shooting round, P1 chooses their leftmost target (Spot 1). P2 chooses their rightmost target (Spot 3). (See Below for diagram)

```
                                (P1) 3 <- Hit   1
                                     2          2 (P2)
                                     1  Miss -> 3
```

For the above example, P1 would miss their shot and P2 would hit their shot, resulting in P1 losing one of their lives. **During the shooting phase, players must choose a barrier to shoot behind, they cannot stay hidden.**

After the shooting phase both players go back into the moving phase and, without their opponents knowledge, can move behind either of the other two objects or stay in place. They then continue to the shooting phase. They loop through these two phases until one of the players run out of lives, both players run out of lives, or a set number of rounds is completed.

#### Inputs

In the first game of the match, no arguments will be supplied to your bot. In each subsequent game of the match, you will be supplied 2 Args. -Arg1 will contain the location of the player([1, 2, or 3]) as well as the players move history. -Arg2 will contain the location of the players shot([1, 2, or 3]) as well as the players shot history. Both of these locations are referenced as if you are looking in the face of your opponent.

Example:

- Round 1: PaintballBot.exe
- Round 2: PaintballBot.exe 1 1
- Round 3: PaintballBot.exe 12 11
- Round 4: PaintballBot.exe 121 113

#### Output

Each round, your bot must output the location in which it is hiding, and the location it is going to shoot, to STDOUT, with two characters. All example outputs are shown below:

`11`
`12`
`13`
`21`
`22`
`23`
`31`
`32`
`33`

#### Match Format

Each submitted bot will play one match against each other bot in the tournament

Each match will last until one of the players loses their x amount of lives, or the match executes 50 rounds.

Matches will be played anonymously, you will not have an advanced knowledge of the specific bot you are playing against, however you may use any and all information you can garner from his decision making during the history of the current match to alter your strategy against your opponent. You may also track history of your previous games to build up patterns/heuristics etc... (See rules below)

#### Submission

Your submission should include:

- Your Bot's name
- Your Code
- A command to

  - execute your bot from the shell e.g.
  - ruby myBot.rb
  - python3 myBot.py
  - OR
  - first compile your both and then execute it. e.g.
  - csc.exe MyBot.cs
  - MyBot.exe

### Sidenotes

- **Need to describe that the location is relative to the shooter(from left to right) and the targets are relative to the shooter(from left to right)**
- **I am still working on the control program for this event, and any help from other is greatly appreciated**

If someone with more experience than me wants to take this over, please let me know. I would rather help with this challenge since it is my first and then have the knowledge and skills to run my own in the future.

Please let me know what still needs more clarification so we can have a fun tournament!

Answer (score 0):

> ### Sandbox Notes
>
> - Is this inflammatory, mean, and liable to draw unwanted and unnecessary attention to low-voted questions in the Network?
> - Better tags?
> - I should probably write a snippet to find all angry Metas.

## Angry Meta

[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

A site on the Stack Exchange network is considered to have an *angry Meta* if the lowest-voted Meta question (possibly closed, but not deleted) on the site is voted lower than the lowest-voted Main question.

For example, at the moment, the lowest-voted question on PPCG.SE is at -32, while the lowest-voted question on Meta.PPCG.SE is at -24. This means that `codegolf` does not have an angry Meta.

On the other hand, the lowest voted question on SoftwareEngineering.SE is at -13, while the lowest-voted question on Meta.SoftwareEngineering.SE is at -17. This means that `softwareengineering` does have an angry Meta.

### Challenge

You will be given the name of a Stack Exchange site, which you can assume will not be Area 51, Stack Apps, Stack Overflow, a subdomain of Stack Overflow (such as the Spanish Stack Overflow), Ask Ubuntu, Super User, Meta.SE, or any other site that whose domain is not of the form `*.stackexchange.com`.

The name will be given as the name of the subdomain (e.g. `codegolf` for PPCG, `puzzling` for Puzzling, `gaming` for Arqade, etc.). You should return one of two **distinct, consistent values** depending on whether the site has an angry Meta or not.

Since this is liable to change over time, I will not provide a list of test cases here, but you can use this Stack Snippet which is the reference implementation:

> *TODO*

Comment: I suppose you mean to say lowest voted **questions** in your PPCG.SE example.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Comment or not comment?

Write a function which given an all lowercase string, return the same string but with characters that are comments turned uppercase.

## Input

Input is a null terminated ASCII string which may contain any of these characters
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz /*\ space newline
Last and only last character is null
You will not need to test for invalid input, such as "stringliterals" etc

## Rules for what is comment

/* causes everything until */ (or end of string) to be comment
// causes everything until newline (or end of string) to be comment
'\' at end of line in a comment causes next line to be a comment aswell

## Output

A copy of the input but with letters which are comments according to the rules above in uppercase, other characters shall remain unchanged

## Examples

```
/comment -> /comment
//comment -> //COMMENT
/*comment -> /*COMMENT
no /*yes*/ no // yes -> no /*YES*/ no // YES

/*          ->              /*
comment                     COMMENT
*/                          */

//\          ->             //\
/*                          /*
not comment                 not comment
//\                         //\
*/                          */
```

[ungolfed](https://tio.run/##lVTbctowEH33V2yZaSTb9TgkbzXOj9Q8KEIETYTUsUUJk/DtdFfYxgbKUF6w9pw9Zy@WZfYm5eEgV6JOoNlZLz54e3CbWqr4MwJtPRhloYTG1/jAW6iIYJiH@FoY4yRHTjoleOlq4JSuy8dCzzBe6DQlTQipIEk0qP3S84LCzVZ7ueLySEKaaBSwnMFPaCMAeslBp1N4KamuGF5rJd6LDg3CVn34gXY6nff40QE4UeJe87oT/fIERsccmZtGNaD@qHrnV9q@wcZ6bdB0a7RVwLFtZRfgljQxxGPwDl4VSLdeK@uHciu3JR1gFQPhu7Qg09qEVkLgKCI6GRDNVhkzqi7Jh6eFg0/YrrRRODAaPzw8nOYN30q0tQziccPQLpQoyJCsGKO4wlFkHyL4F5xw4TCDM6/saV6WrKpYPMrERepZSTuMLt2zTM/Lsfv@bNXd0pKLpd3qoBvIscxsSoXys7Gg4tfX8PUJ0ZxmFV@dVZr@a1rUY/D5j8TLRhdqKTbGY5@j1hwrzqj76IrCXdmYuY/Cpb1@Z7GTfki0TcviXi0cUUUZ3AcRe4BWOHrtXkomcI4nRo9kz0@dxBW0iKi6FsCyqINH5NfKb2rbAkg6UPFroS3Hon/j9fNLPvneVLaykx/dN26St5doggstbtDu5SX38azD78lONUkO9JgDPt9bQlVVVpjGdfe/stZ5uLe@yp7yknwS37YkL8oZOGAghJMcuZSOo/4L)

Comment: Which characters can be in the input? Printable ASCII?

Comment: printable ascii yes and you can also assume input will not contain uppercase letters, function shall change a-z -> A-Z if they would be comment according to C-syntax

Comment: I edited the proposal, clarified and simplified a little bit

Comment: [Potential dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/remove-single-line-and-multiline-comments-from-string). This challenge is about removing comments instead of changing their capitalization, but the main part is the same.

Comment: @Laikoni, thanks I had not seen that one, looks almost the same

Answer (score 0):

## There, I fixed it (with recycled parts)

#### Challenge

Given a string containing only letters `a-z` (either upper- or lowercase), fix it by adding characters to it so that the difference between two adjacent characters is no more than one, or if you can't, remove offending characters (in order) until the string satisfies the requirement.

For example, `abcdfge` must be fixed either by adding an `e`, resulting in `abcdefge`, or by removing `f` and `g`, resulting in `abcde`. Removing must be done only if adding can't be done.

You can add characters only from a recycle bin, which your program or function must store between calls. Characters removed from the string are placed in the recycle bin, and added characters are removed from the bin. The bin can store multiple instances of the same character. In the beginning, the bin is empty.

If you can't fix the whole string by adding characters, don't add any characters. That is, only ever either add or cut a string, not a bit of both.

#### Example

```
First call:
  Recycle bin: "" (empty)
  Input:       "abcdfge"
  Output:      "abcde"          // 'f' and 'g' are removed and placed in the recycle bin

Second call:
  Recycle bin: "fg"
  Input:       "defhiabcdeg"
  Output:      "defghiabcdefg"  // 'f' and 'g' are taken from the recycle bin and placed
                                // where they are needed.

Third call:
  Recycle bin: ""
  Input:       "codegolf"
  Output:      "cdef"           // The two 'o's and the 'g' and the 'l' are removed and
                                // placed in the recycle bin.

Fourth call:
  Recycle bin: "oogl"
  Input:       "mnpqrt"
  Output:      "mn"             // 'o' could be added, but it isn't, because an 's' is
                                // also missing and we don't have one. "pqrt" are added
                                // to the recycle bin.

Fifth call:
  Recycle bin: "ooglpqrt"
  Input:       "kmnrsu"
  Output:      "klmnopqrstu"    // Characters "lopqt" are added from the bin to fill all
                                // the gaps. Unused characters are left in the bin.

Sixth call:
  Recycle bin: "ogr"
  Input:       "qwerty"
  Output:      "qe"             // The gap between 'q' and 'w' can't be fixed so 'q' is
                                // removed. 'e'-'q' < 0 and therefore not more than 1,
                                // so 'e' stays. The rest of the characters are removed.
                                // The recycly bin will contain "ogrwrty".
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the goal is to make your code as short as possible in whatever language you choose to participate with.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: "You can add characters only from a recycle bin, which your program or function must store between calls." Many languages don't have the capability to store information between program runs or function calls, or at least not easily. Perhaps having two inputs (recycle bin, 'input'), and two outputs (recycle bin, 'output') would be more inclusive?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following question then found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110812/find-recursively-prime-primes) question. Is it similar enough to mine that mine would be considered a duplicate?

## Recursive Prime Multiplicative Base

I've been thinking about this idea for months now, and, as far as I have been able to find, nobody else has thought of it. Please let me know if I wasn't the first!

Most number systems are additive positional. These take the form of ∑b<sub>i</sub>*d<sub>i</sub>, where d<sub>i</sub> is the sequence of digits and b<sub>i</sub> is the base sequence. For example, for the number 1234 in base ten, d<sub>i</sub>={4,3,2,1,0,0,0...} and b<sub>i</sub>=10<sup>i</sup>.

I propose the idea of a multiplicative positional system.<sup>1</sup> This instead takes a general form of ∏b<sub>i</sub><sup>d<sub>i</sub></sup>. The most obvious useful multiplicative base is that of b<sub>i</sub>=P<sub>i</sub>, where P<sub>i</sub> is the i-th prime number. For example, one could write 3960 as `3,2,1,0,1`<sup>2</sup>, as 2<sup>3</sup>*3<sup>2</sup>*5<sup>1</sup>*7<sup>0</sup>*11<sup>1</sup>=3960. This is mathematically interesting (e.g. multiplication gets reduced to addition, but addition is way harder) but we're still using an additive system underneath. This obviously cannot do. Thankfully, we can use recursion! This is probably best illustrated with an example:

```
3960=
  3    2   1  0 1
(0 1) (1)  () 0 ()
(0()) (()) () 0 ()
=(0())(())()0()
```

As you can see, each nonzero digit gets replaced with that digit's representation. 1 gets replaced with (), as a blank sequence is equivalent to an infinite series of zeros, and anything to the power of zero is one. If one were to include a symbol representing negation, one could write any rational number and even any expression obtainable from the integers using a finite number of multiplications and exponentiations in a finite sequence of four characters.

To give this number system a name, I term it the **recursive prime multiplicative base** or **RPMB** (unless you have any better ideas for it).

<sup>1</sup>Extending this, one can conceive of an infinite number of [hyperoperational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) positional systems, but that's for another code challenge. ;)

## The Challenge

You are to write a program that, when given an integer as input outputs the RPMB form of that integer. The output may be either as a string or a list. If the output is a string, you may substitute any characters for `()0`. If the output is a list, the output should be a list of 0's and other lists matching this description. For example, for 3960, the program might output `[[0,[]],[[]],[],0,[]]`.

### Examples

(todo)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest program in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139034/encode-an-integer/139040).

Comment: But 9 isn't a prime...

Comment: @user202729 whoops, typo! Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

## Split the wagons! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

In some variants of APL, a tacit function, or a *train*, consists of several functions next to each other. Your task is, given a train, to separate the different functions it consists of.

The symbols you will be given and their meanings are:

- **F**: Function
- **O**: Dyadic operator

Here is how functions are separated in extended Backus-Naur form:

```
function ::= {F O} F
```

Namely, a dyadic operator **O** accepts one function to its left and one **F** to its right, and the result is one function, for example **F O F**, **F O F O F O F** and **F O F O F O F O F O F** are all considered single functions for the purposes of this challenge. **F F F O F O F F F O F**, however, isn't a single function, and is split as (**F**, **F**, **F O F O F**, **F**, **F O F**).

You can get the symbols in any reasonable form, including a string, an array of integers, and any other kind of ordered collection able to hold at least 2 different elements. You can assume the input doesn't start or end with **O**, or contain two **O**s in a row. However, you must always use the same symbols, and you must only use two unique symbols. The output can be one of:

- List of indices (0- or 1-based) which are the locations of the first symbol of each function. The index representing the first symbol of the input can be optionally omitted, as it's implied. The list doesn't have to be ordered.
- List of indices (0- or 1-based) which are the locations of the last symbol of each function. The index representing the last symbol of the input can be optionally omitted, as it's implied. The list doesn't have to be ordered.
- List of the individual functions. Every element of this list is a list subject to the same restrictions as the input, but not necessarily in the same format as the input. However, all elements must have the same format. The list has to be ordered.

Do not include empty partitions or duplicate, out-of-bounds or negative indices in the output.

Below are some test cases. `F` and `O` are used for **F** and **O** respectively, and the output is a list of the separated parts.

```
(empty) -> (empty)
F -> F
FOF -> FOF
FOFOFOF -> FOFOFOF
FOFOFOFOFOF -> FOFOFOFOFOF
FFFOFOFFFOF -> F F FOFOF F FOF
FFOFOFFOF -> F FOFOF FOF
FFFFF -> F F F F F
FOFF -> FOF F
FFFF -> F F F F
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: If replacing all the '3's doesn't fix your code, remove the 4s, too, with 'ceiling(pi) / floor(pi) * pi * r^floor(pi)'. Mmm, floor pie.]

- Output the largest prime number possible in as few bytes as possible using no number but pi.
- [This code](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEIXhvccoHmDSZNrOWtwVqeguFIxt0IEmKWkQPX1M/82Dj@dMeltnEk8m54u186arIbIzC6ffEMOH/etRjYdiPukdzHOx@8Ne9T2cv2u028bB6@NtirymU3DO@Llnb7Wux72cswBEFFIRYlvqpBIKykiADomwkzWpRtStpAYKtyCIlEIB9Ac) will be the sole judge of whether your output is actually a prime number.
- Your score will be the prime number produced divided by the number of bytes used for your code.
- If your language has a built-in variable for pi, use that. Otherwise, let pi equal `3.1415926535898`. Any occurrance of pi itself or something referring directly to pi counts as one byte.
- Your number must be generated solely by applying various operations and functions to pi. Those functions cannot offset pi by anything other than another number derived from pi. The sole exceptions to this rule are floor and ceiling functions. For example, if you want to find the square root of something, you must do something to the effect of raising it to the `(pi/pi/(pi/pi+pi/pi))`th power.
- You may not modify pi in any way that uses a reference to or directly uses non-pi number.
- The entirety of the number must be outputted in base 10 and without scientific notation. All digits of the number must be included in the output.
- You must provide a
- The largest score wins.

Here's an example in Lua:

```
print(math.floor(math.pi))
```

That's 14 bytes (counting `math.pi` as one byte) for the prime number 3, so my score is 3/14 or ~0.21428571428. Here's another example:

```
m=math print(m.floor(m.pi^m.pi)+m.pi/m.pi)
```

That's 31 bytes (each `m.pi` is one byte) for the prime number 37, so my score is 37/31 or ~1.1935483871.

## Sandbox

Are there any other ways to clear up ambiguities I may be missing?

Comment: [some loopholes are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) and are sometimes referred to as "standard loopholes".

Comment: You should include a winning criterion, i.e., "largest score wins" if I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks. I've edited the post

Comment: At some point (and judging by the kind of stuff that happens here) the values being produced will be beyond guaranteed bounds of even strong tests like [Baillie-PSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) (2^64=18446744073709551616). Are such values banned or is it up to others to show that the number produced is composite? For example I might post [``Ç*ÇµḞ+Ḟ×Ḟ+Ċ*`$`` in Jelly](https://tinyurl.com/ybnmbnuv) since it produces `10555134955777783414078330085995832946127396083370199445109` which Baillie-PSW says is a probable prime.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice challenge!

Comment: Oh, by the way, that is `floor(π^π)×(floor(π^π)+floor(π^π))+ceil(π^π)^ceil(π^π)` and [WolframAlpha also *says* it is prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?source=frontpage-immediate-access&i=10555134955777783414078330085995832946127396083370199445109)

Comment: ...Mathematica to the rescue, it has a ["PrimalityProving" package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/guide/PrimalityProvingPackage.html) which we can plug numbers into to check [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEIXhvccoHmDSZNrOWtwVqeguFIxt0IEmKWkQPX1M/82Dj@dMeltnEk8m54u186arIbIzC6ffEMOH/etRjYdiPukdzHOx@8Ne9T2cv2u028bB6@NtirymU3DO@Llnb7Wux72cswBEFFIRYlvqpBIKykiADomwkzWpRtStpAYKtyCIlEIB9Ac) Might be worth including this link.

Comment: Note that [requiring unobservable behavior is discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002). I suggest making the challenge a mathematical challenge and the score is calculated based on (the size of the formula) and (the output). (yes, non-code challenges are allowed)

Comment: Quoting from that answer: "Non-observable requirements tend to be vague, subjective, or based on false assumptions about the properties of programming languages." -- Yes, you're assuming that every language have floating point support, or that every language have the functions you mentioned.

Comment: (1) It's very hard to write prohibitions unambiguously, and I don't think you've succeeded. I don't know what exactly "*Your number must be generated solely by applying various operations and functions to pi. Those functions cannot offset pi by anything other than another number derived from pi.*" allows and forbids. Can I convert pi to a string and take its length? Convert pi to a string, remove the decimal point, and convert back to an integer? Note: answering those two examples would not address the real problem. (2) "*You must provide a*" what?

Comment: I fell it's a busy-beaver

Answer (score 0):

## Relay Adder

Make a 32-bit full adder with relays.

A relay is here a gate with four inputs `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, and output `if A==B then C else D`.

You'll be given two 32-bit numbers (totally 64 inputs), a carry flag, constant 0 and 1, sum up to 67 inputs; output 33 bits as the result

Smallest `Gate count * gate depth` win

TODO: add tags

Comment: Do you foresee any possible gains by making this a 32-bit adder? It feels to me like an 8-bit adder would be sufficiently complicated to allow golfing, without becoming as tedious. What do you mean by: "sup up to 67 inputs?" You also don't define what gate depth is. You also probably want to come up with a way for answers to post readable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## Tell SMILES from FROWNS

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [chemistry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

---

The [**S**implified **M**olecular-**I**nput **L**ine-**E**ntry **S**ystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) file format is used to store structures of organic molecules. For information on why there is an actual file format called "smiles", consult [this comic](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1100) from PhD Comics. As a summary of the format:

- Start the file with a root chain of atoms.
- Put each branch group in parentheses after the atom it connects to.
- Use `=` for a double bond and `#` for a triple bond.
- Break aromatic rings and number the bonds broken; add those numbers after the atoms bordering them.
- Put metal atoms and any ions in square brackets.
- Omit hydrogens attached to carbons. Their presence is assumed.

For example, 1-chloro-3-ethylbenzene could be `C=1(CC)C=CC(Cl)=CC=1`.

## Challenge

Let's make a new acronym, FROWNS: **F**raudulent, **R**idiculous, **O**verbonded, **W**acked, or **N**onexistent **S**MILES. Basically, a SMILES string is a FROWNS string if any of the following apply:

- A loop is unclosed or closed twice.
- An atom from period 2 (Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne) has more than 4 total bonds.
- A neutral nitrogen atom has 4 total bonds.
- An oxygen atom has more than 2 difference of bonds - charge.
- A fluorine atom has anything other than exactly 1 bond.
- Noble gasses other than xenon are bonded.

Your program should determine whether a given SMILES string is a FROWNS string.

Here are some examples of FROWNS:

```
C1=CC=CC=C
CC(C)(C)(C)C
C1=CC=CC=C1C=CN1
C#C#C
C=N=C
CC#O
OFO
FKr(F)(F)(F)(F)F
FXeF(F)(F)
```

These, however, are not FROWNS:

```
C1=CC=CC=C1
CC(C)(C)C
C12=CC=CC=C1C=CN2
C#C
C[N-]C
CC=O
OClO
FXe(F)(F)(F)(F)F
Xe(F)(F)(F)(F)
```

May the shortest code win.

Comment: SMILES is a relatively complicated format, so it might be a good idea to define your own subset of it and set it out in the question, so that people don't have to worry about whether they have to implement aromatic bonds or stereochemistry or what have you

Comment: @Nathaniel my subset called FROWNS is somewhat strictly defined, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't think it's well defined enough. Is `F/N=N/F` a FROWNS string, for example? Technically yes, because it is a SMILES string containing an N with 4 bonds. But do you really need people to support stereochemistry for this challenge? I don't think you do, which is why I suggest you define your own subset of SMILES instead of relying on the relatively complex standard. This will also have the advantage that people won't need to understand organic chemistry to compete in the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Euler's Formula for the Quaternions

Euler's famous formula, `e^iθ = cosθ + isinθ`, can be used to calculate the exponential of arbitrary complex numbers: `e^(a+ib) = e^a(cosb + isinb)`. That's cool and all, but what if we want to go even further?

The quaternions are an expansion of the complex numbers, where instead of just having `i*i = -1`, you have `i*i = j*j = k*k = i*j*k = -1`. Quaternions can be represented as `a + bi + cj + dk` or `(s, v)` where `s` is a scalar and `v` is a 3-Dimensional vector.

Euler's formula can be extended to the quaternions; for an arbitrary quaternion `q = (s, v)`, `e^q = e^s (cos|v|, (v/|v|)sin|v|)`, or, if `q = a + bi + cj + dk` and `r = sqrt(b^2 + c^2 + d^2)`, `e^q = e^a (cosr + (bi + cj + dk)(sinr)/r)`.

#### The task:

Write a program or function to exponentiate arbitrary quaternions. Built-ins are allowed. You may represent a quaternion in any sane manner.

#### Examples

Here, quaternions are represented as a four element array.

```
Input                                    Output (approximately)
0 3.14159 0 0                            -1
0 1 1 1                                  -0.160557 0.56986 0.56986 0.56986
1 2 3 4                                  1.69392 -0.78956 -1.18434 -1.57912
0.095767 0.601479 0.285658 0.926716      0.458433 0.527339 0.250447 0.812487
-0.654682 -0.925557 -0.409382 0.619391   0.194782 -0.37576 -0.166202 0.251462
```

Comment: There's a missing `)` in `e^q = e^a (cosr + (bi + cj + dk)(sinr)/r`

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck Compiler!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

Your goal is simple: Compile brainfuck to x86 assembly (NASM style), and do it with as small of a program as possible. You will be able to choose your compiler's input and output model, as long as the input is brainfuck code and the output is NASM style x86 assembly.

The brainfuck code should read from STDIN and output to STDOUT

Your compiler must be fully compliant with no extensions, and must support a infinite (to the max the computer's memory can sustain, running out of space on either end can be treated as a crash.) number of unsigned 8 bit cells both forward and back, with the tape  Your output assembly should provide the exact same outputs for the corresponding inputs as the brainfuck code.

Your program's output must be compilable to a ELF binary that runs on Linux using the NASM compiler. Your program will be linked with libc, so you can use any function in the C library.

#### What is Brainfuck?

Brainfuck is a language with 8 instructions, and a tape memory model composed of an infinite amount of unsigned 8 bit (1 byte) cells. The pointer always points to one of those cells, executing its operations on the current cell.
Each instruction is executed one at a time, and are as follows:

- `+` Increment the current value under the pointer
- `-` Decrement the current value under the pointer
- `.` Output the value under the pointer as an ASCII character
- `,` Get a character from input, and wait until one is received.
- `>` Move the pointer to the right
- `<` Move the pointer to the left
- `[` Jump to the matching `]` if the value under the pointer is 0
- `]` Jump to the matching `[` if the value under the pointer is not 0

If a `[` doesn't have a matching `]` (or vice versa), you can consider that undefined behavior.

Anything not listed here should be considered a NOP, or in the case of a empty program (EOF), simply a blank, noncrashing program.

#### Test cases.

To allow competition, and varying compilation results, my test cases will show what each test program should output.

Program:

```
"++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>."
```

Outputs (no input):

```
"Hello, World!"
```

Program:

```
+[,.]
```

Outputs:

```
"I am a test string" -> "I am a test string"

"Golfing is fun!" -> "Golfing is fun!"
```

Program:

```
`+[]`
```

Outputs:

Nothing. This program loops forever.

Program:

```
+[<+]
```

Outputs:

This program can be considered undefined behavior, because it will eventually run out of memory.

#### TODO

More test cases?

Comment: is the tape left bounded? also you should specify input behaviour on EOF

Comment: "to the max the computer's memory can sustain" -- I feel that requirement quite problematic. For example, a submission using 16-bit cell (and only use the lower 8-bit, for whatever reason) will only be able to handle half as many cells as one using 8-bit cell.

Comment: @user202729

I'd say a submission like that would be rare enough it's a non issue.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon The tape is unbounded, both left and right.

Comment: For a doubly infinite tape, *to the max the computer's memory can sustain* definitely needs more clarification. For example, if I "run out of space" on the right end, but still have space on the left one, do I need to shift things around?

Comment: Alright. I'll fix that now.

Comment: I think it's better to use 1 side unbounded, as that's usually the convention i think

Answer (score 0):

## Fill a virtual World Cup Sticker Album

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

As the World Cup is due to kick off (pun intended), the inevitable sticker book comes along as well.

According to this [BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-43566749) , at a cost of £0.80 for a pack of 5 and with a total of 682 stickers needed to complete the book it could cost up to £700 or more to fill, taking duplicates into account.

Write the shortest program possible to

- Buy a virtual pack of stickers (at 0.80 per pack), which will be 5
  random numbers between 1 and 682 (or 0 and 681)
- Repeat until all numbers have been picked at least once
- Output how many packs were bought and a final cost.

Output should be in the format "Bought *number* packets at cost of *number*"

**Sample un-golfed Python 2 code**

```
import random
total = 682
remain = total
cost = 0.8
spend = 0.0
packs = 0
got = [0 for i in range(total)]

while remain > 0:
    # buy a packet of stickers
    for i in range(5):
        got[random.randint(0,total-1)] += 1
    spend += cost
    remain = got.count(0)
    packs += 1

print 'Bought %d packs at cost of %.2f' % (packs,spend)
```

**Sample output**

```
Bought 865 packs at cost of 692.00
```

### QUESTION

- Writing the Python script for myself is what made me think of this question - does it help to include it, or clutter the page? (This is my first attempt at a question here)

Comment: You need to flesh out what we're doing? Your code isn't super greatly commented and I'm not sure how much a pack costs, how many packs are needed. etc. should it always output the same amount?

Comment: What does "*simulate*" mean here? Beware the curse of the [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194).

Answer (score 0):

## [Left Turn at Euqreuqebla](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/rsz_bugs_2_4558.jpg)

Write a quine, according to the [standard definition of a quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878), that outputs itself when executed. However, when your code is reversed it should output each character of your source code separated by a newline instead.

---

## Example

If your program was:

```
ABCDEFGH
IJKLMNOP
```

The **unedited program** should output:

```
ABCDEFGH
IJKLMNOP
```

**However the reverse of the program** should output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H


I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
```

---

## Rules:

- Outputting a single trailing or preceding newline is acceptable.
- If your code contains newlines, they do not require rotation, treat them regularly.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Ensure that your "quine" [is actually a quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878).
- This is [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: an example with code with newlines would be useful (as those I'd naturally rotate 90 degrees :p)

Comment: @dzaima which way do you think is better, not requiring "natural rotation" to support Java and the like better? Or supporting natural rotation for the esolangs?

Comment: a thing to consider is that if natural rotation would be required, everyone would just try to keep everything in a single line to make the challenge way easier

Comment: @dzaima I could make it optional? I don't see that hurting the challenge too much either way to be honest, it just lets languages to what they do best.

Comment: that'd be a good compromise if there's no better solution

Comment: @dzaima ehhh? decent?

Comment: usually it's bad to have multiple ways to solve the challenge, though here it's pretty easy to tell which method's gonna be the easiest

Comment: @dzaima exactly, that's why I want to allow it to see if SOGL or some other language with crazy flipping commands can do this the "harder" way.

Comment: If you're going for `Albuquerque` spelled backwards, that's not how it's spelled.

Comment: Shouldn't the example have a gap of three newlines between the `H` and the `I`, not two?

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce great catch.

Answer (score 0):

## Radioactive Quine Sums

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Related: [Radioactive Quines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37755/radioactive-quines)

### Challenge

Write a program that takes an integer as input and....

1. When the program is run it outputs the input.
2. When you split the program in half, each sub-program should take as input the output of the original program, and output a number. The sum of the two numbers should equal the output of the original program.
3. Repeat the procedure with each valid sub-program.

Your score is **byte count/[valid programs]<sup>2</sup>** (lowest score wins).

### Specs

1. When you split an odd-length program in half, the program on the left gets the extra character.
2. For a sub-program to be valid, the sum of its output and its pair's output must be the input, for every possible input *n*, -100≤*n*≤100.
3. A sub-program that doesn't compile/doesn't output a number is invalid (along with its pair).
4. If a program is invalid, it can't be split further.
5. A program that outputs "0" for more than one input can't be split further.

### Testcases

Pseudo-langauge: `A` adds a 0 to the stack, `Q` adds the input to the stack. `-` negates the element to the right of it.The output is the sum of the stack elements.

1. `Q` Score: 1/1 = **1**
2. `AQ` Score: 2/3² = **.222** (`AQ` -> input, `A` + `Q` -> 0 + input)
3. `AAQ`  Score: 3/3² = **.333** (`AAQ` -> input, `AA` + `Q` -> 0 + input) [Since the output of `AA` is 0, you can't split it any further]
4. `QAA` Score: 3/5² = **.12** (`QAA`-> input, `QA` + `A` -> input + 0,
   `Q`+`A` -> input +0) [Since `QA` -> input, `Q` and `A` are valid sub-programs, since the sum of their outputs equals the output of `QA`.]
5. `QAQ` Score: Infinity [Since `QAQ` outputs 2*input, it is invalid and can't be split further.]
6. `QQ-Q` Score: 4/5² = **.16** (`QQ-Q` -> input+input-input,`QQ`+`-Q` -> (input+input)+(-input), `Q`+`Q`->input+input, `-`+`Q`->error) [`Q` and `Q` are valid subprograms of `QQ` because the sum of their outputs is 2*input, which is the output of `QQ`.]

---

Feedback Appreciated

Comment: `0=0+0=(-1)+1`, why can't it be splitted further?

Comment: @user202729 because someone would just leave it always zero

Comment: However I still think score->0 solution exist, so

Comment: For `0=(-1)+1`: Language `W`=output the input `0`=output zero `Q`=quit `WQ0Q0Q0Q0Q0Q0Q0Q` has low score

Comment: @l4m2 and user202729 look at rule 5 in Specs.

Comment: @geokavel we know the rule, just analysing whether they are good here

Comment: @l4m2 yeah, i see your point about `WQ0Q0....` scaling infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

See all the blocks

In a 3D coordinates, a block `(a,b,c)` takes the place of `x<a<x+1, b<y<b+1, c<z<c+1`.

1. Is there a point that can see every block? (Exist point `P`, For each block `K` exist point `Q`, segment `PQ` don't go across any block but `K`)
2. Is there a way that can see every block? (Exist non-zero vector `w`, For each block `K` exist point Q, for each positive number `t`, `Q+wt` is not in other blocks than `K`)

Output four values to represent the four possibles.

Shortest code in bytes win.

Comment: Although the challenge idea is good, we generally expect people to make the challenge reasonably-complete in the sandbox ("write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it"), and not just the ideas. (for example: what is the winning criteria?)

Comment: Also, it appears that there are 2 different challenges here that needs to be solved in very different ways. Consider having 2 different posts.

Answer (score 0):

## Heroes of Might and Magic 0: A Numerical Boxing Match

It's time to program a game!

Well not a game, precisely. More of a stripped-down version of a game, without graphics or real-time input... or really much of anything. But it'll modify numbers on screen, and isn't that why we play games in the first place?

### To elaborate:

If you're unfamiliar with the Heroes of Might and Magic franchise, here's the very most basic workings of the combat system: A stack of creatures of a single type (say, 2 green dragons or 1000 marksmen) will simultaneously attack another stack of creatures of a single type. Each creature does a specific amount of damage, and that's reflected in how many troops in the opposing stack die.

For example, let's have 5 angels vs. 100 skeletons, and let's have the angels go first. If they hit 50 damage each, then 5*50 = 250 damage will be done to the skeletons. If the skeletons each have 10 health, then 250/10 = 25 skeletons will perish, leaving 75.

Next, the skeletons attack. If the skeletons deal 2 damage each and angels have 100 health each, the skeletons will do 2*75 = 150 damage to the angels. But how can we kill 150/100 = 1.5 angels? What happens is that one angel will die, and then the remaining 150-100 = 50 damage is dealt to the top angel in the stack. This angel will be the first to receive damage on the next round and will only require 100-50 = 50 damage to die, but can still deal damage like normal in the meanwhile.

Then angels attack skeletons, skeletons attack angels, angels attack skeletons... repeat until only one stack of creatures remains!

There are loads of other mechanics involved in actual combat, but the fundamental one is attacking, and that's what you'll be programming today.

### Technical Specification

Two stacks of monsters will be attacking each other. Each of these stacks has three properties:

1. Size, positive integer. This is how many total monsters are in the stack.
2. Health, positive integer. This is how much damage is needed to kill ONE.
3. Damage, positive integer. This is how much damage EACH monster in the stack will deal.

When a stack of monsters A attacks a stack of monsters B, all of the monsters attack, dealing

```
A_size * A_damage
```

total damage. This kills a total of

```
floor(A_size * A_damage / B_health)
```

monsters in B. If the damage dealt isn't an even multiple of `B_health`, then the remaining

```
(A_size * A_damage) - (B_health * floor(A_size * A_damage / B_health))
= (A_size * A_damage) % B_health
```

damage is dealt to the top monster in B, which will persist into the next round.

### Input

You'll receive two groups of three numbers, each of which contains information about one stack of monsters: The total number, the health of each individual, and the damage dealt by each individual.

```
[(A_size, A_health, A_damage), (B_size, B_health, B_damage)]
```

You can receive this as two lists/tuples/arrays of three, six separated values in a single line, or six newline-separated values. **The first group of numbers represents the monster that attacks first.**

### Output

After the fight is finished, you must output the number of remaining troops in the winning stack.

### Examples

```
Input: [(1000, 10, 2), (500, 15, 3)]
Output: 763

Input [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
Output: 4

Input [(100, 100, 1), (100, 100, 1)]
Output: 10
```

Lowest byte count wins!

## Feedback

- Is the challenge clear? I feel like it's simple and maybe I'm being too verbose in explaining it, but maybe it isn't.
- Are there any other good ways to accept input?
- Does it seem like it'd make a fun challenge? If not, are there any changes I could make to make the challenge more interesting?
- Anything else?

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that, in different languages, output a different permutation(the exact source is counted as one permutation) of the code.

Proper quine rule apply. Largest (Language count)^6/(Code length) win.

Sample: If your code is `AAB` and running in several languages return `ABA`, `AAB`, `AAB`, then its score is 2^6/3.

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: "Shuffle" implies randomness.  I'm assuming that this isn't what you want:  "Ordering" is a better term:  You want a set of programs that output the same bytes, but in different orders.

Comment: Or "permutation".

Comment: Do the output need to be valid (executable) source code or it may be mess of reordered characters?

Answer (score 0):

## The 3n+1 problem

[The legendary problem in UVa Online Judge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36), with [over 775k submissions and over 85k people who solved it](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=problem_stats&problemid=36&category=24). I, personally, have solved it in many ways, even reaching the best time below 0.01 sec.

Even though the problem is interesting from the algorithmic point of view, insofar as reasonable time constraints would be easily able to force people to think about some sane approach to caching and use data structures like the segment tree, it is actually not the case here: the time constraints, on UVa, are so lax that even a purely naive algorithm is accepted by the judge. Since we are on CodeGolf and not on a programming contest, we aim here to write shortest code, and not necessarily fastest one, so for most part you don't need to care about performance - that is, as long as it is not horrible even beyond the lax allowances of the online judge; more on that below.

## The input

The input will consist of several lines, each containing a pair of integers *i* and *j*, such that *0<i,j<1,000,000*.

## The output

For each line of input, you are to print one line of output that will consist of integers *i* and *j*, in that order, followed by one number that will denote the maximum length of the [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) (also known as the 3n+1 sequence), over all numbers between and including *i* and *j*. Note that while in mathematics the terminal number *1* usually doesn't count to the length of the sequence, in this problem it does.

The Collatz sequence is defined as follows: If *a<sub>n</sub>* is odd, then *a<sub>n+1</sub>:=3*a<sub>n</sub>+1*; or, if *a<sub>n</sub>* is even, then *a<sub>n+1</sub>:=a<sub>n</sub>/2*. The sequence ends when it reaches number *1*.

## Sample input (taken from UVa):

```
1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000
```

## Sample output (taken from UVa):

```
1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174
```

## Additional notes:

- There is no guarantee that *i<=j*. The input may contain lines with *i>j*. However, even in these cases, you are supposed to print out *i* and *j* in the output in the correct order (that is, *i* comes before *j*, not *min(i, j)* before *max(i, j)*.
- There is a guarantee that, while computing the Collatz sequence terms, no term will overflow a 32bit integer.
- As of now, the [problem specification](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) gives incorrect input boundaries, claiming that all numbers will be less than 10,000. The correct bound seems to be 1,000,000 instead, which is present in the [archived version of the problem specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225044321/https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36). Since last time I checked the judge required accepted programs to be able to process numbers up to 1,000,000, we retain that requirement in our problem.
- Your program must perform actual computations. Hardcoding all sequence lengths for numbers between *1* and *1,000,000* is unacceptable. So is fetching them from external sources.
- Your program must read from standard input and write to standard output. Your program must format its output as required by UVa Online Judge for this program.
- Of course, we do not retain the original harsh requirements on acceptable programming languages. Any programming language is OK as long as it doesn't violate the standard loopholes.
- Your program must correctly process all lines until EOF and then exit gracefully. Your program must not wait endlessly on EOF, enter an infinite loop on EOF, crash on EOF, exit with an error, etc.
- Performance restrictions:

  - Basically, the intention is to allow everything but most horribly underperforming programs.
  - To be more specific, the naive algorithm that, for each line of input, computes once the whole sequence for each number in the required range is allowed ([example of an allowed program](https://ideone.com/fsyca5)). It is also allowed to keep an array caching lengths of all sequences starting with numbers from *1* to *1,000,000* ([example of an allowed program](https://ideone.com/JRZOjF)), or to keep a dictionary caching lengths of all sequences starting with any encoutered numbers so far ([example of an allowed program](https://ideone.com/2tA6W1)); however, it is not allowed to keep an array caching all encountered lengths, since that array would be unreasonably sparce and thus unreasonably large ([example of a disallowed program](https://ideone.com/UW541X)); it is also not allowed to precompute a *1,000,000x1,000,000* array that would keep all maximums of lengths in all valid ranges ([example of a disallowed program](https://ideone.com/rRD1vz)). Your program may precompute lengths even for numbers that would otherwise be disallowed by the guarantee of not overflowing a 32bit integer ([example of an allowed program](https://ideone.com/R7Bp2L)), if you wish.

**Shortest code wins.**

Comment: From a golfing perspective, this looks like basically [the usual Collatz challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12177/20260), taking the max over an interval but with [Cumbersome I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260) and [non-observable performance requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20260).

Comment: @xnor , I don't think these requirements are non-observable, my intention was to disallow everything the judge disallows without imposing the programming language restrictions; anyway; a `1,000,000x1,000,000` array of integers is around `3.5TB`!! - I think disallowing this makes sense? Basically my intention was to prevent saying that "In a computer with unlimited resources this program would complete and is therefore valid". If I want to disallow this, am I supposed to rather prepare my own test case and run the program on my computer to see if it fits in reasonable time/space requirements?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding the restrictions then -- is what you intend is just a hard bound on run-time and memory, and the types of programs that work are just examples? Regardless though, I expect it not to matter as golfed programs will just compute the whole sequence for each number in the range, which you allow. All the optimizations seem like they'd take more characters.

Comment: ... yes, to have such requirements you have to run it yourself (or ask someone to do this for you) Although, if as you said (almost every algorithm) are allowed, what's the point in having another challenge? I would call this a dupe.

Comment: One more point: If there exists a programming language where hardcoding 10⁶ terms is shorter than computing them, you should reconsider the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## ___ encrypting

Given two text `a` and `b`, both contain only lowercase letters

1. Write each charactor in `a` into 5 digits of binary (`a => 00001`, `z => 11010`)
2. Write each charactor in `b` where such place of the binary list is `1` is written into a different style (uppercase, bold, etc., but should be consistant)
3. If some char remain in `b`, either keep them all in the `0` style or remove them. You can assume `b` has enough chars.

Sample:

`a` = `cat`, `b` = `programmingpuzzlescodegolf`

1. Write `a` into binary `000110000110100`
2. So the output can be  `proGRammiNGpUzz`, `proGRammiNGpUzzlescodegolf`, pro**gr**ammi**ng**p**u**zzlescodegolf, etc.

Comment: You should probably mention a specific win condition.

Answer (score 0):

## A Magic Ritual

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Given an input string N perform a sequence of steps.

1. Delete all spaces from the string.
2. Delete all other occurrences that come after the first one of the same letter from the string.
3. If the string contains the letters needed for `zero`, delete these letters and add the corresponding digit `0` to the end of the string. Repeat this for 0 to 9.
4. Order the characters left in the string by the alphabet, then by their numeric values.

### Input

May be received as a string, an array of characters or any other reasonable input for text.

You may assume that the input will only consist of characters including a-z (lowercase) and spaces.

### Output

Same as input, or may be directly written to `stdout`.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in terms of bytecount wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Test Cases

```
a magic ritual -> acgilmrtu
sixone -> 16
codegolf -> cdefglo
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog -> abcdfghjklmnpqtuvwy06
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm -> abcdfghjklmnpqtuvwy06
```

Comment: Do `second occurrences` include 3rd 4th etc?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

### Title: The Liquorice All-sort

I have just invented a new sorting algorithm, which I would like you to implement in the smallest number of bytes... The *Liquorice All-sort*

Given that the individual sweets are (or were) named: chips, rocks, Buttons`[sic]`, nuggets, plugs, twists, spogs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquorice_allsorts), we can say that:

A bag (multiset) of `Liquorice allsorts` is comprised of 0..n of each item `chip, rock, Button, nugget, plug, twist, spog`, plus a bonus of 1..2 `Bertie`.

Given an input of an arbitrary array characters (`A-z`, `0-9`, `space`), and a bag of Liquorice allsorts, sort as follows:

```
For each input character, from last to first:
    Is the bag empty?
           Yes: Exit the sort
    Else, Is the input equal to a letter (case-sensitive) that is contained in the name of one or more of the sweets in the bag?
       Yes: The number of items it matches is the number of positions it moves up the list (can't move past the top of the list).
            Take a bite out of each of the used sweets, by removing the letter we used. 
            Have we used all the letters in any item?
               Yes: Remove that item from the bag
    Else: move to the bottom of the list.
```

### Inputs

two inputs - the numbers to sort, and the list of sweet names. Both are guaranteed to be non-empty bags (sets that can contain duplicates; or an equivalent in your language), and the bags of sweets contains a minimum of one `Bertie`.

### Outputs

The sorted numbers

### Examples

1. `{Bertie},{B}` -> `{B}`
2. `{Bertie},{X,B}` -> `{B,X}`
3. `{chip, rock, Button, nugget, plug, twist, spog, Bertie}, {A,B,C,k,e,r,w}` -> {B,C,k,e,r,w,`A`} -> {`B`,C,k,e,r,w,A} -> {B,k,e,r,w,A,`C`} -> {`k`,B,e,r,w,A,C} -> {`e`,k,B,r,w,A,C} -> {e,`r`,k,B,w,A,C} -> {e,r,k,`w`,B,A,C}
4. `{Bertie, rock}, {r,o,c,k,r,o,c,e}` -> {`r`,o,c,k,r,o,c,e} -> {`o`,r,c,k,r,o,c,e} -> {o,`c`,r,k,r,o,c,e} -> {o,c,`k`,r,r,o,c,e} -> (remove rock from the bag) -> {o,c,k,r,o,c,e,`r`} -> {o,c,k,r,c,e,r,`o`} -> {o,c,k,r,e,r,o,`c`} -> {o,c,k,`e`,r,r,o,c}

### Sandbox Questions

I really like the idea of doing something with this (I like the wordplay of `bag`, etc.); but I don't know if the algorithm is just too arbitrary. Any thoughts or alternatives would be appreciated!

Comment: Absolutely not. (although you're encouraged to post your sandbox challenges when they're ready)

Comment: You only have 3 challenges in the Sandbox at the moment; some people have north of 30 - You don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

## Count the Matches

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)

---

Given a stripped-down regular expression, estimate (rules below) the number of lower-ASCII-only strings that it matches fully (meaning it matches the whole string).

You should handle the following:

- Literals/sequencing
- Vertical bars `...|...`
- Groups `(...)` or `(?:...)`
- Special characters escaped with a preceding `\`
- Character classes `[...]`
- Complemented classes `[^...]`
- The standard classes `.`, `\d`, `\w`, `\s`, `\D`, `\W`, and `\S`
- The escape sequences `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\xhh`
- The quantifiers `?`, `{x}`, and `{a,b}`

## Estimation Rules

### Literals

Literals, obviously, match only one string.

```
aaaaa --> 1
```

### Classes

The estimate for a class is the number of characters that it can match. If multiple are seen, then their individual counts can be multiplied. There are also the standard classes: `\d` is `[0-9]`, `\w` is `[_A-Za-z\d]`, and `\s` is `[ \n\t\r]`. `\D`, `\W`, and `\S` are the complements of their lowercase versions.

```
a.b --> 127
\D --> 118
[a-gd-k] --> 11
[^\w$A] --> 64
[abc][xyz] --> 9
\d\d\d --> 1000
```

### Switches

Switches (vertical bars) should be estimated as the sum of the component expressions.

```
a|a --> 2
a|b --> 2
(0|1)[01] --> 4
0|1[01] --> 3
optional| --> 2
```

### Quantifiers

With a static quantifier, you can treat it as a power function. With a variable quantifier, you can use the geometric sequence formula to get the estimate:

*a<sub>1</sub>* is the first term, in this case the estimate at the lower bound. *r* is the common ratio, for which you should use the estimate for the group quantified. *n* is the number of terms, which is the upper bound minus lower bound plus one for the quantifier.

```
[01]{10} --> 1024
.? --> 128
[01]{3,10} --> 2040
0|[12]{3} --> 9
(0|[12]){3} --> 27
\d{30,40} --> 99999999999000000000000000000000000000000
(?:a{2,3}){2,3} --> 12
```

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: The examples require support for sequencing, which is not listed as something which must be supported. The standard classes with upper case are not explained. `(?:...)` is mis-labelled: it's a *non*-capturing group.

Comment: Also what's the charset? `0-127`?

Comment: @l4m2 it's lower ASCII, so yes.

Comment: ASCII sometimes onlt mean 32-126 though

Comment: @l4m2 that's *printable* ascii.

Answer (score 0):

### Rock, Paper, Scissors, Load, Shoot, Block, Mirror, Plasma-shot, Ammo-block, Punch, Bazooka, Super load, and so on and so forth

This is an abomination of a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge.
Two bots are fighting to the death, but the rules keep changing.

Each turn both bots have the same set of 3 random actions from this list as their input:

> L - Load. Gives you 1 ammo.
>
> S - Shoot. Costs 1 ammo, you win.
>
> B - Block. Prevents the opponent from winning this turn
>
> P - Paper. If your opponent chooses the first option in the list, you win.
>
> C - Scissors. If your opponent chooses the second option in the list, you win.
>
> R - Rock. If your opponent chooses the third option in the list, you win.
>
> H - Punch. You win.
>
> A - Plasma. Costs 2 ammo, you win
>
> O - Ammo Block. Costs 1 ammo, prevent the opponent from winning this turn
>
> Z - Bazooka. Costs 3 ammo, you win. This cannot be blocked.
>
> E - Ammo Paper. Costs 1 ammo, if your opponent chooses the first option in the list, you win.
>
> X - Ammo Scissors. Costs 1 ammo, if your opponent chooses the second option in the list, you win.
>
> K - Ammo Rock. Costs 1 ammo, if your opponent chooses the third option in the list, you win.
>
> U - Super Load. Gives you 2 ammo.
>
> D - Defeat. Instantly Lose.
>
> I - Strike. Prevent your opponent from winning. If your opponent wasn't trying 
>   to win, you win.
>
> N - Nothing. Does nothing.
>
> M - Mirror. If your opponent would win, you win instead.
>
> W - Wild. Allows you to do anything.
>
> T - Take. Take 1 ammo from your opponent.
>
> G - Gloat. Win if you have more ammo than your opponent
>
> J - Joker. Does a random action.
>
> Q - Quintuple Load. Gives you 5 ammo.
>
> Y - Lucky. 50/50 chance of winning or losing.
>
> V - Victory. Win the game, unblockable.

Each bot must choose 1 action to do. Actions happen simultaneously, and if two players win at the same time, then the player who spent more ammo to win is the winner (So a Punch would lose to a Plasma).

#### NOTES

Each bot is played 1000 times against every other bot. The winner is the bot with the most total wins.

The 3 actions are selected before each turn. Actions can appear multiple times ("PPB" is possible).

Your bot can see what the opponent did, the set of actions available, ammo counts, and move histories.

If you don't have enough ammo, then your action is treated as an N.

If you choose an invalid action, then you lose.

Comment: Some things to consider:
Do bots start with no ammo? This could be a problem if the first round picks only ammo moves.
Why is nothing an option? Maybe nothing can be a "no move" pick to avoid forced suicide when no ammo is left.
How do RPS work if the there are multiple options? Can bot 1 pick P1 and bot 2 pick P2, giving 2 the win?
What is the difference between Joker and Wild?
What is the point of an ammo-costing block? Currently doesn't seem to do anything.
Mirror is likely to cause only draws since there's (hardly) any reason to pick anything else. Strike is similar.
cont.

Comment: Do Lucky/Coin Flip (duplicate effect by the way) cause your opponent to win, or just you to not win?
Load, super load, and take don't seem to be often worth a turn.
Is there ever a reason to play defeat?
I think you should focus a bit more on the core ammo preservation/more ammo beats less ammo theme. Personally I feel that right now there are too many unrelated/underpowered moves that water down the best aspects of this challenge. Going with an unweighted random pick, ammo consumption in moves seems way higher than ammo resupply allows.

Comment: And along with that pile of questions, welcome to the site!

Comment: If the only inputs are 3 of the differents actions, how are we able to know opponent informations ?

Comment: "if two players win at the same time, then the player who spent more ammo to win is the winner (So a Punch would lose to a Plasma)" but what if they both play the same 'winning' move?

Comment: @aoemica Yeah I kind of wrote them all down at 10 o clock trying to get one for every letter in the alphabet, so there were bound to be some mistakes.  First of all, Joker does something random, while Wild means any action can be chosen (With "PBW" you can choose "M" because of the wild). Lucky can cause you to lose. I'm probably going to replace Coin Flip with Four Load, so you can get more ammo. Rock Paper and Scissors are based on the order. For example, "RNH" means that Rock would beat Punch. It's based on the order "RPS". I'm also going to remove the negative ammo thing.

Comment: @aoemica About the Ammo block, it is pointless if you can do Block, but because the actions you can do are random, you might get Ammo block without Block.

Comment: -1 This challenge has too much randomness, and requires the bot to understand *all* of those rules to be competitive.

Comment: What does "unblockable" mean?  Is Mirror blocking?  Strike?

Comment: This is too complicated. I suggest reducing it to the first 6 items on the list, which should all be available at all times. Or better yet, have the Rock/Paper/Scissors + load variants, shoot, and block

Answer (score 0):

### Cleanup after Easter

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

As most people (probably) know, Easter was about a month ago. But around the community park, there're still some eggs hidden! Can you build a (Javascript only, please) bot to help us find them?

**The Course:**

The bots will compete on a 201 by 201 field, with coordinates ranging from (-100,-100) to (100,100). All bots will start at (0,0) and will begin. The course has 3 types of areas: wall, egg, and grass.

**Finding Eggs:**

You will build a function to find the Easter eggs. To see, use the function `checkZone(x,y)`. The ouputs are:

```
0=Grass
1=Wall
2=Egg
3=Bot
```

To find a player, use `findPlayer(name)` (Returns coordinates array) or `detectPlayers(x,y)` (Returns name or `null`). If your bot lands on a spot with an egg, it will not be able to pick it up until it uses the function `fetchEgg()`. If there is not an egg, your turn will stop.

**Moving:**

Moving is done by returning a string. This string can be `north`, `south`, `east`, `west`, or `none`. Assume that directions are like a compass placed on a Cartesian plane:

```
North=Y+1
East=X+1
South=Y-1
West=X-1
```

**Winning:**

When all eggs are found, the game is over. If you move North to an egg, you must pick it up on the next turn in order to obtain it. If you try to move into a wall, nothing will happen. To get your current position, use `getLocation()`, which returns an array `[x,y]`. Use `getBasket()` to get how many eggs you have. The course will be designed so that all eggs are accessible, but some may be hard to get. If an egg is found by two bots in the same turn, each bot get 0.5 added to their basket, as they split the reward.

**Functions list:**

```
checkZone(x,y): Returns an integer, takes 2 integers as parameters between -100 and 100
    0=Empty
    1=Wall
    2=Egg
findPlayer(name): Takes string as parameter, returns player's position as an array of integers or null if player is nonexistant
detectPlayers(x,y):  Returns an array of player names, takes 2 integers as parameters between -100 and 100
fetchEgg(): Fetches egg in current position if exists
getLocation(): Returns array with x and y coordinates
getBasket(): Returns number of eggs in basket
move functions: Returns true or ends turn (Ends turn if cannot move)
```

**Example:**

```
function rabbitInDisguise() {
    var loc = getLocation();
    if (getLocation(loc[0], loc[1]) == 2) {
        fetchEgg();
    } else {
        if (getLocation(loc[0], loc[1] + 1)) {
            moveNorth();
        } else {
            moveEast();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Added `findPlayer(name)` and `detectPlayers(x,y)` functions, made locating functions "background", and added simultaneous egg finding rules

**UPDATE 2:** Added functions list

Comment: 1. I don't see the competition here.  I find egg, and I grab it as fast as I can.  2. You don't describe what other players look like.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Whichever bot is best at searching for the eggs will win. If `Bot A` moves in circles around the board, but `Bot B` scans a 5 x 5 area around it and makes a map, who do you think would win? Also, what do you mean by "You don't describe what other players look like."

Comment: @user202729 Mistype...I'm about to fix it

Comment: And how does program interact with each other? Is there any limit on how many (library) function call can be done in each function?

Comment: `it cannot run more than one function per turn`

Comment: 2. You said that 0=grass, 1=Wall, and 2=Egg.  What does a player look like?  1. Right, let me check all the locations nearest me, and walk to the closest one.  (You can *slightly* improve on this by identifying eggs that other players will go for).  `it cannot run more than one function per turn`:  Your example bot breaks that.

Comment: Players are invisible, since it could complicate things. I'll edit to address the problems, though.

Comment: If players are invisible, then this is not a KotH.  This is a code-challenge to retrieve the eggs as fast as possible.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Fixed. Players can be found using `findPlayer()` and `detectPlayers()`

Comment: So they can investigate the whole board in one turn? Sounds more interesting then.

Comment: @user202729 I think `moveRandom()` would be fine (It just makes it easier to program), but I'll add more info on the functions.

Comment: @user202729 Good point. Feature eliminated.

Comment: Any other problems you can think of?

Comment: One trick would be to use `detectPlayers(0,0)` in the first turn to get a list of all players.

Comment: @NathanMerrill are there any other possible problems to figure out before I post this?

Comment: @user202729 forgot about time zones (:

Comment: "If you move North to an egg [...]" what about other directions?

Comment: @user202729 The rabbit is not very smart. And, he didn't want to spend an hour building an example. But I'll fix the `moveRandom()`

Comment: Are moves synchronized or is there a turn order?  What does "Ends turn" mean?  Are you going to throw an exception or something?  Why not just say "does nothing"?  What's to stop me from checking the entire world every turn?

Comment: @user202729 Turn ends (@NathanMerrill ending turn just stops the function)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms That doesn't make sense.  getLocation() returns an *array*.  It has to do "something".  Say that it returns null, and that the move functions "do nothing", instead of "ending the turn" (which isn't true)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Please elaborate. What do you mean by `getLocation() returns an array. It has to do "something"`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms If I call getLocation(), you say that it returns an array.  Your function *has* to return an array (or null) for Java to compile.  What does your function return?

Comment: @NathanMerrill It returns an array [x,y]

Comment: You may want to explain more. `1` How are functions called relative to each other? (if I understood correctly, all players act simultaneously on the board) `2` What if there are 3 or more bots find the same eggs at the same turn? `3` What does "end turn" mean, does it throw an exception for the caller to catch? `4` (nitpick) Does `getLocation` return in order `[x,y]` or `[y,x]`? `5` > "If you move North to an egg [...]" what about other directions? (does that imply that if we are on an egg we must pick it only if we move North to it?)

Comment: @user202729 `1` All move functions are run first. Then, egg fetching. Then detection and player listing. `2` Each bot would get a third of an egg `3` An exception is thrown, and no other functions are permitted to run that turn (In case the user is sneaky and tries to catch an exception). Note that the functions are run in the order they are called, but the actions are performed in an order. `4` The `x` always comes first, basically Cartesian plane coordinates `5` My _rabbitInDisguise_ function is very basic, and just detects any eggs North of it. You could easily add all sorts of stuff.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms `3` Honestly, I recommend instantly quitting the simulation if an invalid input is given.  You then disqualify the submission until fixed.  It's useful for testing, and you don't have to worry about stuff like "no other actions can be performed".

Comment: Someone might get mad if their bit is disqualified for bumping into a wall...the end turn only stops further actions in that cycle/turn/move. (Like scanning the course for eggs after you hit a wall)

Comment: I don't think this challenge is worth fixing, but for future reference: KISS applies as much to KotH as to anything else. If there is a lot of information which is available without restriction, pass it as input rather than requiring submissions to use a language-specific API to retrieve it. There's no good reason for this to be JS-only.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (what does KISS stand for?)

Comment: @user202729, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/87/13258

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's easier for me to do javascript-only

Comment: How would a javascript bot and a C++ bot coordinate?

Comment: See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/king-of-the-hill/info

Answer (score 0):

## Clebsch-Gordon coefficients

Clebsch-Gordon coefficients are numbers that arise when adding two quantum mechanical angular momenta. Angular momentum is a vector in three-space and can be described by two numbers *j* and *m*. The magnitude of the momentum can be determined by *j* and its z-component can be determined by *m* (more on this below).

For quantum mechanical particles, *j* can only take on nonnegative integer or positive half integer values (`0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2...`). Additionally, its z-component *m* can only take on values between *j* and *-j* inclusive in integer steps. For example if  *j*=**1**, *m* can hold values **-1**, **0** or **1**. If *j*=**3/2**, *m* can have values **-3/2**, **-1/2**, **1/2** or **3/2**.

If an angular momentum has magnitude *j* and z component *m* we say it is in the state |*j*,*m*⟩. The state can be thought of as a column vector in an infinite dimensional vector space (Hilbert space). It is infinite because there is no upper bound for the value *j* can take on. From now on when I refer to an angular momentum I will just use it's state to reference it.

### **j<sup>2</sup>** and **j<sub>z</sub>** operators

I have picked the states |*j*,*m*⟩ such that they are eigenvectors of the operators **j<sup>2</sup>** and **j<sub>z</sub>**. These operators can be thought of as matrices in the infinite dimensional vector space. Eigenvectors of **j<sup>2</sup>** have eigenvalue equal to a states total angular momentum squared. The eigenvalue of a state operated on by **j<sub>z</sub>** is the state's z-component of its angular momentum. The eigenvalues for a state |*j*,*m*⟩ are shown below.

**j<sup>2</sup>**|*j*,*m*⟩=*j*(*j*+1)|*j*,*m*⟩

**j<sub>z</sub>**|*j*,*m*⟩=*m*|*j*,*m*⟩.

In words, the square of the magnitude of the angular momentum of state |*j*,*m*⟩ is *j*(*j*+1) and the z-component of the angular momentum of this state is simply *m*.

Side notes which do not affect the challenge and you can choose to ignore:

- We could have just as easily chosen x or y instead of z but the **j<sub>i</sub>** operators do not commute so we must decide on one only to create our basis vectors. All **j<sub>i</sub>** commute with **j<sup>2</sup>**.
- I have set ħ=1.

Now let's say we have a composite angular momentum with total angular momentum *J* and z-component *M* made up of two individual angular momenta. As you might have guessed, this is the state |*J*,*M*⟩. We can make equivalent operators **J<sup>2</sup>**= and **J<sub>z</sub>**. In order for |*J*,*M*⟩ to be an eigenvector of both of these operators is equal to a linear combination of outer products between states |*j<sub>1</sub>*,*m<sub>1</sub>*⟩ and |*j<sub>2</sub>*,*m<sub>2</sub>*⟩.

If the angular momenta that compose |*J*,*M*⟩ are in states |*j*<sub>1</sub>,*m*<sub>1</sub>⟩ and |*j*<sub>1</sub>,*m*<sub>1</sub>⟩...

[image: Clebsch-Gordon explicit formula]

Image from wikipedia.

### Sandbox

This is an early stage of writing the challenge, but feedback is welcome. If you are familiar with Clebsch-Gordon coefficients I would appreciate any input. They are important in group theory but I am less familiar with that side of them, so if you have a good way of explaining them in that context that would be helpful.

I plan on asking for the square of the coefficients so as not to worry about floating point numbers.

- Should I require sign of the coefficients as well or just magnitude?

Comment: Might be useful: Mathematica's built-in [ClebschGordan](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClebschGordan.html), which you can test on the [open sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com).

Comment: It's not clear to me what the inputs are, and therefore what the outputs are. It's also not clear what the range of the sum is: the entire support?

Comment: @petertaylor yes, thanks I still need to addbthatvinfo

Comment: @lastresort thanks! I did see there was a built in :)

Comment: What's the challenge here?

Answer (score 0):

Do other programming languages allow **post-assignment**, like R?
Can you force it?

In many programming languages assignment works like this, where a value such as 5 is assigned to x.

```
int x = 5; // C++

x = 5 # etc ... // Python
```

But in R, you can do this (and this is the first I've ever heard of this):

```
5 -> x # where 5 is assigned to x in reverse order.
```

This has some advantages. You can do several operations and then save the results to a variable at the end, stopping the operations. As an example,

```
library(dplyr) # allows then (%>%) statements 

(1:10) %>% square() %>% sum() -> y
```

where I define an array of numbers 1 to 10: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},

square each of those: {1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2, 6^2, 7^2, 8^2, 9^2 , 10^2},

sum up the sequence 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2, 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2

and assign that sum of squares to variable y.

y holds a value of 385, matter of fact.

To do something like that, though I would have to define a square function:

```
square <- function(x){return(x * x)}
```

You assignment is to create a post-assignment overloaded operator like "->" which allows assignment like 5 -> x.

Bonus points if the overloaded assignment operator is variable type insensitive, working on numbers, characters, strings, etc ...

Comment: This will need an objective winning criterion.

Comment: It'll need to be more tightly specified as well? E.g. what precisely counts as 'a post-assignment overloaded operator like "->"' and what doesn't? Bear in mind that the concept of "overloaded operator" doesn't exist in a lot of languages.

Comment: I don't see the advantage in your example. C# can do `var y = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x => x*x).Sum()` which seems to accomplish the same thing without needing post-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

## Go Fish!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)

---

"Go Fish" is a childhood card game where you try to obtain pairs by either drawing from the deck or taking them from the other players.

The rules can vary by who you ask, but the rules that this challenge will use are these:

- Everyone starts with a hand of five cards.
- Play goes in a circle.
- On your turn, you can call a card and another player.

  - If that player has that card in their hand, then you get it from them.
  - Otherwise, you draw a new card from the deck. If the deck is empty, you don't get anything.
- If you have two of the same card, then both are removed from your hand and set aside.
- The game lasts until the deck and all players' hands are empty, or until the deck is empty and there are no pairs made for 2 full circles.
- The winner is the player that ends with the most pairs.

There will be 20 rounds with every bot in them in random order. The winner will be the bot that gets the most *cumulative* matches across all rounds.

## The Deck

There will be 40 unique cards in the deck, each identified by a string. Each one will appear twice in the deck for each bot in play.

## Implementation

To do as soon as I finish the runner.

---

For the unique cards, I was thinking of doing a fish theme. Examples include:

- Water-type pokémon
- State fish for various states
- Commands, functions, or programs in ><> and *><>

Any other ideas?

Comment: 1. "*There will be 40 unique cards ... Each one will appear twice*". If they appear twice, they're not unique. 2. This is missing important details about the tournament structure. How many bots per game? How many games will each bot participate in? What will determine the opponents? What are bots allowed to remember between games? Are there points for finishing second, third, etc?

Comment: @PeterTaylor unique meaning different.

Comment: I'd recommend just using numbers to identify the cards, just to prevent bloating the challenge too much

Answer (score 0):

## PPCG Generalist Countdown

Write a function or program that takes no input and returns or outputs the current minimum number of new questions required for PPCG to hand out Generalist badges. Internet access is only allowed to the Stack Exchange API.

The badges are handed out when the top 40 tags (measured by question count) each have at least 200 questions.

Standard loopholes are disallowed. This is code-golf, so the shortest entry wins!

[stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

Comment: You need to explicitly say what internet access is allowed, as accessing the internet is [disallowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/20198)

Comment: I'm not sure this adds much beyond the 30+ [tag:stack-exchange-api] questions we already have ...

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Perhaps try to solve it and see how hard it is to port?

Answer (score 0):

**Given equations, determine values** *(what would be a good title?)*

Given these equations as input, write a program that determines which variable has the greatest, and which has the smallest value.

**Equations:**

```
x             <   y
2x            <   y + z
2x + 2y + z   <   2x + y + z
x,y,z         !=   0
```

**Rules:**

- Your code must mathematically determine which variable has the greatest/smallest value.
- As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: 1. These aren't equations: they're inequalities. 2. One example does not constitute a specification. What limits are there on the number and type of variables, equations, terms, etc? 3. The given example doesn't have a solution. I think the only basic relationships that can be deduced are `x < y < 0`. `z` could be smaller than `x` or greater than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

**Building a Structured Outline**

In a fictional document management system, input documents are structured with weighted headings. Lowest weighted headings are the most important.

This is a sample document:

H1 All About Birds

H2 Kinds of Birds

H3 The Finch

H3 The Swan

H2 Habitats

H3 Wetlands

From this document we would like to produce an outline using nested ordered lists in HTML, which would look like this when rendered:

- All About Birds

  Kinds of Birds

  ```
  The Finch 

  The Swan
  ```

  Habitats

  ```
  Wetlands
  ```

Your code only needs to take the input list and transform it into the expected data structure, which will be printed and checked against the expected output.

Comment: What's the winning criteria? (did you know what does "winning criteria" mean? Read the on topic page of the help center)

Comment: 1. Are the blank lines in the sample document going to be in actual input, or are they just there to avoid the lines merging? (If the latter, ending a line with two spaces inserts a line break; and formatting as code using four spaces at the start of each line is a better option for sample input anyway). 2. Will all lines begin with `H`, a number, and a space? 3. What is the range of possible numbers? 4. Does whitespace matter in the output? 5. When you say "expected data structure", does that mean that the output is something other than a string?

Comment: 1. The child items are indented (as as result of parsing them as HTML later) 2. yes, exactly as in the sample input. 3. <h1> to <h6> 4. no, it will be parsed as HTML 5. yes, List

Comment: Unrelated to this challenge, but [I've just created this Sandbox post based on your deleted Time challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16330/52210). Let me know if you want to post it yourself in 72 hours, since it was originally your challenge. If you don't want to post it anymore I'll post it myself (with your permission). Either is fine by me. :)

Comment: Please edit the post to add more information instead of answering in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Infer the type

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(This is not finished yet.)

## Task

Implement the type inference algorithm for Hindley-Milner lambda calculus.

## Data Types

The data types in this challenge is (in Haskell):

```
data Kind  = Star | KindFunc Kind Kind
data Type  = TypeName String  | TypeVar String | App Type Type
data Value = ValueName String | ValueFunc String Type | App Value Value
```

If your language doesn't support ADT or if using it will make the program longer, you can use any isomorphic representation.

You can assume that there is no name conflict, nor unbound name.

## Theory

### Value

In Hindley-Milner system,every value has a single most general type. For example the type of `Just 5` is `Maybe Int` (Note that in Hindley-Milner type system, unlike Haskell, doesn't have any typeclass).

If a function value has type `A -> B`, you can call it with argument with type `A` to produce `B`. Additionally, you can use a lambda. A `\x -> y` has type `type(x) -> type(y)`. (type(x) means the type of value x). However, if you try to apply a value of type `A` to function with type `B -> C` type unification between A and B occurs (explained below)

### Type

Like a value, type is composed from smaller type, so that if `K` has kind "a -> b", and a has type "a", the type `K a` has kind "b". The example of the type is `String`, `->`, `Maybe`, `Either String`, and `EitherT String` which has kind `*`, `* -> * -> *`, `* -> *`, `*`, and `(* -> *) -> *` (Assuming EitherT has kind `* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *`. Every value has type *. However, the type can be generic. So a value of `Nothing` has type `Maybe a`. Here, `a` can stand for any type.

### Type Unification

(TODO : To be filled tomorrow)

## Input

The input is a:

1. list of pair of type name and the its kind
2. list of pair of value name and its type
3. and a value to be infered

## Output

Either the type of the supplied input or error if there is type mismatch.

## Example

(Here we use Haskell notation for the input, it is not recomended in actual challenge because it will unecessarily make the program longer)

```
> Types  : Maybe :: * -> *, Bool :: *
> Values : Just :: a -> Maybe a, Nothing :: Maybe a, True :: Bool, False :: Bool, maybe :: (a -> b) -> b -> Maybe a -> b, compose :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> (c -> b)
> Infer  : \f -> maybe (compose Just f) Nothing
> Result : (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
> Infer  : \f -> maybe (compose Just f) True
> Result : Type error
```

Comment: 1. A question should be self-contained. What is the specification of the type inference? What are a *kind*, a *type*, and a *value*? 2. A question should avoid imposing non-observable requirements. In other words, the specification should say what types should be inferred, but not dictate the algorithm. 3. It's not obvious how to map the example to the data types given above. I don't see any constructor names.

Answer (score 0):

## The true spirit of "Hello World!"

A hello world program is traditionally the first program you write in a language you've never tried before. So we're gonna make some true hello world programs here. Your challenge is to golf a hello world program in a language you've never used before.

Once you've posted your best attempt, you are welcome to accept help from others in the comments, including those who've used that language before, but please leave a copy of your original attempt, and use <s>strikethrough</s> on previous byte counts.

#### Rules based on honesty of participants:

- Really pick one you've never used before. Different versions (python 2 / python 3) don't count.
- Don't look at any other codegolf pages other than "tips for golfing in  [your language]". Hello world has been golfed in many languages on PPCG but copying would be boring. The point is for each participant to have fun trying something new.

#### Objective rules, copied from the Hello World catalog challenge (who's answers you are not allowed to look at):

- Each submission must be a full program.
- The program must take no input, and print `Hello, World!` to STDOUT (this exact byte stream, including capitalization and punctuation) plus an optional trailing newline, and nothing else.
- The program must not write anything to STDERR.
- Submissions are scored in *bytes*, in an appropriate (pre-existing) encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8.

## Notes for the Sandbox:

-Will people understand the point of this challenge? I want people to realize that, while PPCG is unlikely to see any novel solutions here, this challenge will still be a challenge for each participant. In fact, even the top-scoring master golfers will have a challenge: to find a language they haven't used ;).

-Is the title obnoxious? Suggestions?

-This is supposed to be a fun challenge for learning and teaching. Will people get that, or will people get really competitive and look for loopholes in the honesty-based rules?

-Should I tag it popularity-contest despite asking for golfed code, just so that people realize it's not supposed to be super-competitive?

Comment: Although the idea is interesting, I don't think this should be hosted on this site (because the answer length would be >= length of existing post anyway). Perhaps in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)? Or make a chat room for that?

Comment: I see what you're saying with the >= existing answers thing. Would that still be an issue if it was tagged popularity contest?

Comment: Popularity contests are notoriously difficult to get right. Only 3 of the past 15 have been accepted as good by the community. As-is, this would likely get closed as *Too Broad* because it's basically "Do X Creatively."

Comment: It would probably also get tagged as a dupe of the original `Hello, World! `question

Answer (score 0):

## Page size changing

Given positive integer `m` and `n` both > 1, and array(maybe-empty ordered list) `A` consist of integers in `[0,m)`(0-based) or `(0,m]`(1-based), output an array `B` consist of integers in `[0,n)`(0-based) or `(0,n]`(1-based) such that, when given input `m'=n, n'=m, A'=B`, the output is `A`.

You are not allowed to use built-in large number. To be clear, the number you use should be at most polynomial to `(m+n)*arrlength`. (discussing, ban/penalty/just allow)

Example: if you output `[1,2,3]` for `m=6, n=8, A=[4,3,2,1]`, then you have to output `[4,3,2,1]` for `m=8, n=6, A=[1,2,3]`.

Shortest code win.

Comment: Is there any way simpler than implementing bijective base conversion? Otherwise it's just "implement big integer division"?

Comment: I think there be

Comment: you use "array" presumably this means a non-empty ordered list .. a tuple .. thus A and B are each in a space isomorphic to Z but with representations in base m and n respectively .. why not say so

Answer (score 0):

## Bananagrams

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [crossword](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossword)

---

Bananagrams is a tile-based word game where you race to make crosswords and use all your letters before everyone else does. In the original game, finishing your crossword allows you to say "peel", causing everyone to draw another letter tile. Whoever finishes their crossword when there are no more letter tiles to draw is the winner.

## Challenge

You will be given a list of letter tiles and your task is to arrange them into a  crossword using [this list of alphabetic words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt) as your dictionary. In the spirit of the board game, you need to do this as quickly as possible.

## Input and Output

Input to your solution will be a list of letters and you should output a grid of letters. You will need to read in the list of words.

As an example: given `abcdeiloopswy`, your program/function might produce

```
cowboy
  a l
  side
  p
```

## Test cases for timing

- `aabcdeeefghiijklmnoopqrssttuuvwxy`

*more TBA*

## Rules

- No abusing standard loopholes
- Input and output may be in any convenient format.
- You must load the linked word list exactly, not a stripped down version.
- You may assume that you will be given only lowercase letters
- You may assume that there is at least one possible crossword from your given set of letters.
- This is a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, so the answer with the shortest execution time in each language wins.

  - Be sure to post execution time and CPU as part of your solution.

Comment: Why do solutions need to be written in Python? What if a solution calls out from Python to another language?

Comment: @isaacg: one way or another, there needs to be a way to compare solutions on performance. The other option would be to make a test driver for several languages, but I don't want to write 10 test drivers.

Comment: I don't see why you need a test driver like that. Just require submissions to read from a file and write their outputs to a file, and have your test script read their file to evaluate their solutions.

Comment: @isaacg: how would I be able to score on execution time? I guess I could ditch that as a scoring requirement in favor of a time limit.

Comment: Time the execution of the submission, with something like the `time` command. Or require submissions to time themselves. I'm not suggesting you change your rules at all, just use different timing.

Comment: @Beefster (`time` command is a Linux utility, which can be used to measure the execution time of any process, which is also what TIO used to measure the time, however do note that TIO is not acceptable for measuring time)

Comment: @isaacg: How would I adjust for differences in language speeds? Solutions in C would have a massive advantage over solutions in pretty much any other language.

Comment: @user202729: See above comment

Comment: @Beefster A lot of the time, algorithmic speed is more important than complilation quality, so it'll matter what language the program is easiest to write fast code in, which is not always C. Take a look at past [tag:fastest-code] contests. C++, Rust, and Nim are popular.

Comment: @isaacg: After looking around, you have me convinced. I thought language advantages were a bigger deal than they really were.

Comment: I'm not a fastest-code expert (ask Dennis for more details?), but I'm afraid that using a "sample benchmark program" doesn't solve the "on which machine" issue, because on some machines some operations can be done faster than other machines.

Answer (score 0):

#### Palindromic Sum

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base)

> For some all bases g ≥ 5, we prove that any positive integer can be written as a sum of three palindromes in base g.

This is the theorem proven in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06208.pdf) by Cilleruelo, Luca, Baxter.

#### Challenge

Given a positive integer `n` and a base `g ≥ 5` find three palindromic numbers in base `g` that sum to `n`.

#### Details

- You cannot use leading zeros to make a number count as a palindrome, that means the most significant digit of a palindrome must be nonzero. (In base 10, the number `01210 = 1210` is not considered as a palindrome.)
- The submissions must be able to process any aribtrarily large input `n` (within the memory limits). It is not sufficient to use finite precision integers, i.e. 32-bit `int`s.
- The integers in the input and output can be in the format of native integer types, as strings in any fixed base (not dependent on `g`), or as list of digits in any fixed base (not dependent on `g`) or in the base `g` or as number in the base `g`.

Comment: Forbidding finite precision integers doesn't sit well with me, and it doesn't seem particularly vital to the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Take an expression containing variables and these functions, check whether it's true:

```
1 int  one()          1
- int  neg(int)       -a
+ int  add(int, int)  a+b
- int  sub(int, int)  a-b
* int  mul(int, int)  a*b
> bool gt (int, int)  a>b
< bool lt (int, int)  a<b
= bool eq (int, int)  a==b
& bool and(bool,bool) a&b
| bool or (bool,bool) a|b
! bool not(bool)      !a
 bool nand(bool,bool) !(a&b)
^ bool xor(bool,bool) a^b, or (a&!b)|(!a&b)
  bool imp(bool,bool) !a|b
... (any bool function, with any amount of input)
E bool any(var, expr) whether a be any value make expr true
A bool all(var, expr) whether a be all value make expr true
```

You can take input in any reasonable format. You can define what "variable" look like as long as there can be infinite possible different variables. Removing some functions is allowed as long as it doesn't reduce the ability of expressing, i.e. some calculatable function can convert expression with all functions possibly exist into the model you removed something. Redefining the function name or merging some symbols is also allowed.

To solve the problem, you are given another input source `G`. You need to solve the problem correctly when `G[0] -> inf, G[1] > any_function(G[0]), G[2] > any_function(G[1]) ...`.

Sandbox Notes:

it's quite a fix of [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16128/gg), but it's using haltable as output while I use another input source to help solve.

Comment: I understand what you're doing here. If you're OK with it, I'll adapt my version and post it, since it's more complete at the moment.

Comment: Now it looks similar to your previous "solve the halting problem" challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Pressure unit conversion

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In my line of work I often need to convert between four different pressure units: `bar`, `psi`, `MPa` and `kgf/cm2`.

**Challenge**

Write a program or function that does the following:

- The user enters a value, the original unit and the conversion unit
- The program or function makes the conversion
- It then prints out the result in the form: `[Starting value] [Starting unit] = [Converted value] [Converted unit]` with spaces between all items.

For example with inputs `15.25`, `psi` and `kgf/cm2`, the program would print out the following:

`15.25 psi = 0.07030695796 kgf/cm2`

**Rules**

- The allowed range of input values can be in your language's standard floating-point type.
- Input can be arguments, come from STDIN, or whatever is your language's preferred form of input.
- The input units don't have to be literal strings - you can use other pre-defined values if you want.
- However, the output must use the literal of the units: `bar`, `psi`, `MPa` and `kgf/cm2`.
- Both `kgf/cm²` and `kgf/cm2` are acceptable.
- If printing out the result isn't feasible then you can return the string that would have been printed out.
- This is code golf - shortest answer wins!

**Conversion values**

The conversion values are:

```
1 bar = 14.50377377 psi
1 bar = 0.1 MPa
1 bar = 1.019716213 kgf/cm²
1 psi = 0.06894757293 bar
1 psi = 0.006894757293 MPa
1 psi = 0.07030695796 kgf/cm²
1 MPa = 10 bar
1 MPa = 145.0377377 psi
1 MPa = 10.19716213 kgf/cm²
1 kgf/cm² = 0.980665 bar
1 kgf/cm² = 14.22334331 psi
1 kgf/cm² = 0.0980665 MPa
```

**Some test cases:**

```
33.4 bar = 484.426044 psi
19 kgf/cm2 = 1.8632635 MPa
65 MPa = 650 bar
-59.002 kgf/cm2 = -839.2057018 psi
23 bar = 23 bar
0 psi = 0 kgf/cm2
1 MPa = 1 MPa
```

I took these sample values from [here](http://calculator.org/property.aspx?name=pressure). You can use it too for more test cases.

### Sandbox Questions

- Is four pressure units all right, or is it too many? My gut tells me that four makes it just complex enough, but I'm also worried that it's just adding extra information without any extra challenge.
- I'm not certain if I should restrict the input as well as the output. I think restricting the output format adds to the challenge, but restricting the input would make the challenge too, well, restrictive.
- I should display the conversion values in a more machine-readable form, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[editor-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editor-golf) [matrices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices)

### Intro

Many fans of high-powered editors like to learn new tricks. For example, [vimgolf.com](http://vimgolf.com): "Real Vim ninjas count every keystroke".

### Goal

Produce this diagonal matrix in a text editor:

```
0000000000
0100000000
0020000000
0003000000
0000400000
0000050000
0000006000
0000000700
0000000080
0000000009
```

### Winning criterion

Fewest keystrokes wins

### Rules

- Need to do it in a text editor
- All pre-existing packages are allowed
- Must start from an empty page
- No copy/pasting external content

### Explanation

- Say which editor
- Present the total number of keystrokes
- Provide a list of keystrokes, and say what each one does
- Link to any packages used, so we can check them out!

---

See [Is editor golf on-topic?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/is-editor-golf-on-topic) for more info on editor golf.

Comment: -1 for text editor restriction, -1 for pre-existing packages, "must start from empty page" and "copy/pasting" are common sense/standard loopholes. "say which language/number of keystrokes/provide a list of keystrokes" is required in all code-golf challenges

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! First of all good job for using the Sandbox, since a lot of new users do not. The tags you've added both doesn't exist, `[tag:matrix]` does exist however, but `editor-golf` not ([tag lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags)). I'm also a bit confused about the challenge. Do we need to use any programming language, and create that output in a `.txt` file? Or do we actually use text editors like Notepad, Notepad++, VIM editor, etc. and use their default commands to get the result in as few commands / key-pressed as possible. I'm assuming the second if I read correctly.

Comment: re: packages - for all we know someone has already made a package to do it in one key :P

Comment: See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/is-editor-golf-on-topic for more info on editor golf.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Right, the intent is to use the commands available in a text editor like vim or emacs.

Comment: @ASCII-only If there's a package for doing cool stuff like that in one key, I want to know about it! : )

Comment: What determines whether something is a "text editor" or not? Is Microsoft Word one? Because that would allow you to use VBA macros. How about a programming environment like Eclipse? You can edit text documents in such a program. This needs to be a little better defined before it gets my upvote.

Comment: [Challenges should not limit possible languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231). I can't see any problem from allowing e.g. Python to compete.

Comment: Although, let people vote. **Note** Please upvote if you think that limiting it to editors only is good (despite the fact that it can be ambiguous, as AdmBorkBork said in the comment above), or downvote it if you think that this can be made language agnostic.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156936/the-cell-at-the-end-of-the-rainbow) is the latest well-received language-specific challenge, if I recalled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## How Many Cards Can You Play This Turn?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Given a deck of cards L, where each card has an nonnegative integer mana cost, and two nonnegative integers x, representing the mana you have this turn, and n, representing the number of cards you draw from the deck, output the average highest number of cards you can play this turn.

i.e. given an array of nonnegative integers L and nonnegative integers x and n, create the subset N by choosing n random elements of L. Find the average of the maximum number of elements in N that sum to no greater than x.

### Examples

For example, L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x = 1, n = 1. You get 1 mana this turn and draw 1 card at random, from a deck of cards with mana cost 0...6. Since there is a 1/7 chance of drawing any card and you only have 1 mana, there is a 2/7 chance you can play the 1 card you draw (0 or 1) and a 5/7 chance you can’t play the card you draw (2...6). Therefore the average max number of cards that can be played is 2/7 = 0.286

For a more complicated example, L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x = 10, n = 4. You get 10 mana and draw 4 cards from the same deck as above. There are 7 choose 4 = 35 different possible hands. Of this, there are only 2 hands in which only two cards can be played (3,4,5,6 and 2,4,5,6). There are 22 hands where 3 cards can be played and 11 hands where 4 cards can be played. Therefore, the average max number of cards that can be played is (2*2 + 3*22 + 11*4) / 35 = 114/35 = 3.257

### Specifications

- The input must be a list of nonnegative integers, L, and two nonnegative integers, x and n.
- You may assume n <= len(L), i.e. you cannot draw more cards than are in the deck
- The output must be either a decimal which has at least 3 digits of precision or an exact fraction
- The distribution for each element of L must be equal
- Standard I/O methods apply and standard loopholes forbidden
- This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
Input: L (the deck), x (mana), n (cards drawn)
-> Output: average max # of cards played this turn (fraction for reference)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1, 1 -> 0.286 (2/7)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2, 2 -> 0.810 (17/21)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3, 3 -> 1.457 (51/35)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10, 3 -> 2.686 (94/35)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10, 4 -> 3.257 (114/35)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10, 5 -> 3.762 (79/21)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1, 0 -> 0
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, 3 -> 3
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 1, 3 -> 0

[0, 16, 4, 9, 3], 7, 2 -> 1.2 (12/10)
[11, 0, 3, 19, 6, 8, 15], 20, 4 -> 2.686 (94/35)
[14, 3, 2, 11, 5, 3, 9, 2, 10], 20, 6 -> 3.976 (334/84)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164760/orthodiagonal-steps)

Answer (score 0):

## Source in n bytes

Write a program `A` and an integer `K` that, when given a number `n>=K`, your program generates a program(in same language) of length `n` that generates the source program `A` and don't if some characters are removed.

Smallest `K` for each language win.

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Comment: What do you mean by "and don't if some characters are removed"? Any example?

Comment: @tsh generates the source program A and don't generates the source program A if some character(s) of your generated source are removed, so you don't just fill the code with unnecessary space/etc

Comment: So it's similar to a pristine program?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't generate program A if some characters removed"? Do you mean "for any sub character sequence S of source A, program S have different behavior to program A"?

Comment: @tsh your program generates a program(in same language) of length n called `P` that outputs `A`, for any sub character sequence S of source P, program S have different behavior to program P(so don't output A)

Comment: This looks to me like a generalised quine. If a simple quine diagonalises `f(Y):print Y`, this diagonalises `f(Y):if len("....")>X:print Y`. There are some subtleties around the length of `X`, but I'm not sure how much this adds to existing quine questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor For example, we have `function () { source = ...; if (length(source)=10000) return source; else "9900 bytes padding"; }` then its sub sequence  `function () { source = ...; if (length(source)=1000) return source; else "900 bytes padding"; }`  should just work.

Comment: @tsh, I have no idea what you mean. I'm not even sure whether your example is meant to support my point or contradict it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think tsh can support or contradict your idea, depending on your meaning

Answer (score 0):

### Calculator tape

There is an infinite amount of calculators in a row (supporting the four basic operations, +, -, *, and /), all initially displaying "0". They have a peculiar property that any calculator which has a result lower than either the one to its left or right stop accepting any button presses except "=".

Besides the calculators is an operator who follows certain instructions and presses their buttons accordingly.

Unfortunately, the operator is a bit lazy and has asked you to write a program which would simulate all of this for him and then output a list of all nonzero calculator results.

#### Calculators and operations

Every calculator has three registers, one which stores the input, one which stores the last result, and one which stores the currently selected operation (+, -, *, /).
In the beginning, the input and result registers are `unset`, acting as 0 if adding/subtracting or 1 if multiplying/dividing. The operation starts as `+`.

The operations available are the following:

- `0`..`9` - Append the digit to the input of the selected calculator, without changing its result.
- `#` (±) - Change the sign of the input. Note that this might be executed even when the input is 0.
- `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` - Evaluate the current operation, then set the operation accordingly and reset the input. As it changes the result, it might change the disabled statuses of calculators.
- `=` - Evaluate the current operation and reset the input. Don't reset the operation.
  Unlike the other operations, this operation works even when the calculator has a lower result than its adjacent calculators.
- `<`, `>` - Select the previous or the next calculator, similar to BF.

#### Input and output

Input is going to be a string or list of operations to be done. The characters used to represent the individual operations need not be the same as outlined above, but must be distinct.

Output should be a list (in any format) composed of nonzero calculator results and their indices. The indices might start from any number, as long as it is identical between runs.

Examples:

```
Input  ->  Output # comment
1  ->  # The calculator's result is 0
1=  -> 0: 1 # The = operation evaluates result + input = 0 + 1 = 1
1#=  -> 0: -1
#1=  -> 0: -1 # Note that this results in input being -0 for a moment
1=>2=  ->  0: 1 # The second calculator does not work while the first is larger
1#=>2=  ->  0: -1, 1: 2 # Results start at 0, so negative results don't disable
1>2=<=  ->  0: 1, 1: 2 # = Works on otherwise-disabled calculators
4*4>1+2=<=  ->  0: 16 # * changes the result to 4, thus disabling others
```

### Meta

- As it currently stands, there are too few complicated examples, mainly because it is too easy to disable a calculator. Would be nice to have some which have multiple adjacent calculators with the same result.
- There is too little inter-calculator interaction past the disabling mechanic. Maybe some way to read a result as input?
- The third point might be yours! Comment to claim it ;)

Comment: What character encoding is `±` in? Can we assume Windows-1252 where `±` is 0xB1? (I suggest using an ASCII-only substitution, like `#`)

Comment: > "The characters used to represent the individual operations need not be the same as outlined above, but must be distinct." -- the idea was that golfers might pick a different character, for example `$` or `#`. Anyway, I will replace `±` with `#` so it would be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

## Tired Sumo Fighters

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

This is a simple KOTH challenge in which you program a bot to push other bots out of a ring. Each round consists of two bots, and every bot will compete against each other bot at least 10 times. The reason that this KOTH is different from other similar KOTHs is that the bot only is very tired, so it only has a little bit of energy, and it cannot waste it.

### Moving

Your bot can move around the ring (An 11x11 square) using one of 10 commands:

```
moveForward() //Moves forward
moveLeft() //Moves left
moveBackward() //Moves backward
moveRight() //Moves right
moveToward() //Moves toward enemy
moveAway() //Moves away from enemy
approachCenter() //Moves toward center of ring
approachEdge() //Moves away from center of ring
moveCounterClockwise() //Moves counter-clockwise around ring
moveClockwise() //Moves clockwise around ring
```

However, each movement takes energy. As a parameter, set the energy consumption (Defaults 1). If one bot stays still and the other runs into it, the moving bot pushes the still bot. If the bots run into each other, the bot who allotted more energy pushes. If there is a tie, the bots do not move.

### Pushing

Say that bot 1 and bot 2 are fighting. If bot 1 is at position (-4,5) and bot 2 is at (-2,5), there is one space between them. If each bot moves toward the opponent, the one who spent more energy moves forward. If there is a tie, the bots do not move. If a bot has any coordinate with an absolute value greater than 5, it loses. If any bot has energy under 0, it loses. It is possible to live with 0 energy, but you will be quickly pushed out of the ring. **Every bot starts with 200 energy**

### Detection

To find your opponent or yourself, use these commands:

```
locateSelf() //Returns as array [x,y]
locateOpponent() //Returns as array
energyLevel() //Returns your energy level
opponentEnergy() //Returns opponent's energy
```

### Example

```
function sumoChamp() {
    if (energyLevel() > opponentEnergy()) {
        moveToward(5);
    } else {
        moveCounterClockwise(2);
    }
}
```

As you can see, a basic sumo bot takes just a few lines. However, a smart sumo bot would be able to overpower it, and a genius bot could even figure out its pattern and destroy it. You cannot build systems designed to target specific bots that have already been designed. To save information for later, store it in your bot's function, like this:

```
sumoChamp.opponentResearch.avgEnergy = 4
```

## Rules

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/75524) not allowed

Entries can be in any language that supports functions and arrays, but all entries will be converted to JavaScript before the game starts.

Comment: There should be more specification. What's the exact distance the bot will be pushed?

Comment: @user202729 1 space

Comment: Perhaps my understanding is not complete, however would there be an optimum solution that would either guarantee a win or tie? i.e. move to the centre of the ring and then subequently push the opponent toward the outside of the ring with half of the remaining energy that you have each step. If the opponent uses less energy they are pushed, otherwise they will have wasted more energy than the first bot and eventually run out of energy prior to the first bot, thus get push out

Answer (score 0):

## K-th largest element

Find the k-th largest element of n elements in at worst O(n)

It shouldn't be affected by

- element arranging
- element range
- RNG (if you use)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

Comment: This can be done with a heapify algorithm in O(n). Not that complicated.

Comment: @Beefster But (1) it's not trivial (at least for golfing languages, C++ has built-in `nth_element`) and (2) your algorithm is wrong (it takes O(n+k log n), which is about O(n log n) for k in O(n))

Comment: "O(n)" implies "at worst O(n)". Big-O notation only upper-bound the complexity, it doesn't lower-bound. (so an algorithm that is O(n) is also O(n²), O(n!), ...)

Comment: Also, please "Write your challenge just as you would when actually posting it." -- people find it hard to understand your posts, so it would have a lower change of them not understanding your challenge.

Comment: To the two people who have upvoted this answer: @user202729's point is relevant to you too. Do you seriously think this is *ready to post* with just a title and tags?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No because of the character limit xd (I thought it was a 0 vote, didn't know it's a +2/-2)

Comment: @user202729 `nth_element` is average O(n), worst O(n^2) iirc?

Comment: ... I think so. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) says "O(n) on average", and doesn't specify the worst case behavior. You may want to add "the algorithm must have deterministic runtime".

Answer (score 0):

## Construct any Sporadic Simple Group

There are 26 [sporadic simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_group). Your task is to write a program which defines an operation isomorphic any of these groups.

**Input**: Two symbols that represent elements of the group. You can choose how these symbols will be represented (characters, numbers etc.).

**Output**: The result of the operation on the input.

Taken as a whole, the operator defined must be isomorphic to one of the 26 sporadic groups.

*I don't actually know anything about group theory; I haven't even taken a course in it yet, just read some Wikipedia and thought this could be interesting. If it isn't trivially solvable, maybe someone could post it?*

Comment: I think this has potential but needs a bit of work. 1. As it stands, it's almost 26 questions in one. Intuitively I would expect the smallest group to be the most golfable, but to really be sure I'd have to make a semi-serious effort with all 26. I suggest picking one group or at most one family of groups. 2. "*Symbols*" is a bit vague. I'm not sure whether I'd be allowed to use an array which must be a permutation of the numbers `0` to `N` for suitable `N` (which is the obvious way of doing some if not all of the groups). 3. You haven't specified a winning condition. I assume [tag:code-golf].

Comment: 4. (Hadn't thought of this when I wrote 2). Since every finite group is a permutation group, with a suitable input format this can be reduced to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1490/194 . So if you want to tackle it as group action, you need to constrain the input representation and running time quite harshly. However, it reminds me of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26423/194 where golfing a representation of a simpler perm group was an interesting subtask. The solution might be to ask to generate all elements of the group in a non-trivial representation (as perms or reduced words).

Answer (score 0):

> **Meta**
>
> Polyomino detection itself is a duplicate. And there was also a very similar question concerning simple connectedness of a tiling pattern. So I won't submit.

## Holey polyomino

A [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) is a plane polygon consisting of equally-sized squares connected at edges. A polyomino might have a hole if it contains a region with a square on all four sides.

## The challenge

Determine if a collection of squares is a polyomino with a hole.

### Input

The input will be a matrix of 0s and 1s, where a 1 indicates a square in that position. For example, the top left nonomino in the picture above could be:

### Output

A truthy or falsey value for whether the input represents a polynomino with a hole.

### Test cases

Arrays of rows:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]] => TRUE

[[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]] => FALSE
```

Comment: Are holes of size greater than 1 considered?  For example (as a list of rows since formatting is limited in comments) `[[1111] [1001] [1111]]`

Comment: @Kamil Drakari yes, that counts. I'll add a test case. And there's no need for the input to be square, so I'll change that too.

Comment: Proposed test case `[[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]] => FALSE` to cover the situation where there's an empty square with non-empty squares in all four directions but which still has a path to the exterior.

Comment: I don't think this challenge is likely to get much traction. I've just proposed a simpler "Is this a polyomino?" question which I think should go first, and might open up possibilities for other challenges.

Comment: The simpler one is, as I wrote in a comment there [a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154363/31516). This one is not a duplicate AFAIK, so you should stick with this one (if any).

Comment: Can there be two (or more) holes?

Comment: @StewieGriffin I've deleted the other one. And this one is very close to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69030/triangular-grids-simply-connected-polyiamonds so I don't think I would proceed.

Comment: @StewieGriffin the two-or-more hole thing could work, but I would be inclined to make it a question about topology rather than polyominoes. As in "calculate the genus of this surface" where the surface is represented by the binary array as in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

## Go shopping!

You're shopping for four specific items. Your town contains fifteen shopping malls. Unfortunately you can't always find the item you want at the nearest mall. You want see whether you can purchase the four items on a single shopping trip. [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

For each item, there is a list of malls (given as coordinates) where the item can be purchased. Some malls however will only sell you a given item if you visit that mall first. Furthermore, the entrances and exits to the malls are badly placed and you can only visit malls in increasing order of coordinates.

Examples:

1. Item 1 can be purchased at mall (7, 2) but only if you visit that mall first. It can also be purchased at mall (3, 1).
2. Item 2 can be purchased at mall (7, 1).
3. Item 3 can be purchased at mall (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2) or (6, 2).
4. Item 4 can be purchased at mall (7, 2).

With this scenario, it's not possible to purchase both items 2 and 3 in one trip.

1. Item 1 can be purchased at mall (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3).
2. Item 2 can be purchased at mall (3, 2), (4, 2), (3, 3) or (4, 3).
3. Item 3 can be purchased at mall (6, 1), (7, 1), (6, 2) or (7, 2).
4. Item 4 can be purchased at mall (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1) or (7, 1), but only if you visit that mall first.

In this secnario, you would visit mall (4, 1), (4, 2), (6, 2), and then (6, 3), and successfully purchase all four items on a single trip.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: 1. "*(given as coordinates)*": always 2D and in integers? 2. "*Some malls however will only sell you a given item if you visit that mall first.*" How is this indicated in the input? 3. "*in increasing order of coordinates.*" What's the order in dimensions higher than 1D? Lexicographic?

Comment: I think your two examples need more separation. It was difficult to tell whether the middle "With this scenario..." line connects to the first, second, or both lists. I would add "Example 1:..." and "Example 2:..." to show the distinction.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Yes. 2. I don't mind how that special case is indicated in the input; you could have two separate lists, or a boolean with the coordinates. 3. You can choose which coordinate(s) to increase.

Comment: How come in the first scenario I can't go `(3,1) (3,2) (7,1) (7,2)` and purchase all four items? Do items need to be bought in order? If so, that should be explicitly stated.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork You can't go from (3, 2) to (7, 1) because 1 < 2. (And you can't go from (2, 3), to (1, 7) either, for the same reason.)

Comment: Ah, *both* coordinates need to be non-decreasing. That could probably be made a little more clear.

Comment: This should be reflavored as an IKEA trip. :P

Answer (score 0):

## Softcode

**Softcoding** is an anti-pattern defined by “*the practice of removing ‘things that should be in source code’ from source code and placing them in some external resource*”, which usually are config files, database entries, or both. “*At the extreme end, soft-coded programs develop their own poorly designed and implemented scripting languages*”, as can be seen by one of the most egregious examples of the practice, the Enterprise Rules Engine.

Thus, programmers who fall to the habit of softcoding, after tons of work, find themselves at the very point they were starting from: they have developed “*some sort of **CO**mmon **B**usiness-**O**riented **L**anguage that’s generic enough to code any rule*”. But unfortunately for them, there already is such a thing. “*It’s called C++. And Java. And C#. And Basic. And, dare I say, COBOL.*”

For the sources of the above quotations are more information of the practise, see: [Soft Coding on The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Soft_Coding), [Softcoding on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) and [The Enterprise Rules Engine on The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Enterprise_Rules_Engine).

## The Challenge

**Softcode**! Make an actual, Turing-complete language that will reside in config files!

More specifically, you should write a compiler / interpreter / anything in between that will define a Turing-complete programming language, whose every valid source code will also be a valid JSON file. <sup>(The reason why JSON has been chosen is the simplicity of syntax and wide avalability of JSON parsers, so that you won't have to write a parser yourself.)</sup>

Input/output format is up to you.

## The catch

Not your interpreter code should be golfed. **Your JSON code should be golfed**. Or, more specifically, golfable. That is: you will have to present a JSON file that, if fed to your program, will solve a given golfing challenge and will have smallest size out of all JSON files presented here. This will determine the winner; the size of the interpreter code is not relevant.

## Technical details

Unfortunately, given how this challenge is defined, if I would define any particular problem your JSON-program should solve, one could get away with a simple trick of defining one particular command in one's JSON programming-language that solves this particular problem. To instead encourage creating a language that is as concise as possible, this challenge will be split into two phases. Phase 1 will last a month since posting this challenge; you will then write your compilers or interpretes. Then I will, on random, choose one challenge from this site that has at least 5 upvotes. <sup>([If this challenge proves unsuitable for this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/debunking-stroustrups-debunking-of-the-myth-c-is-for-large-complicated-pro/44283), I'll roll the dice again.)</sup> Afterwards, Phase 2 will begin, when you will present a JSON-program that solves this challenge.

**Be creative.**

## Example interpreter

For reference, below is a simple JS interpreter of a Turing-complete JSON programming language. Of course, it does not strive to define a language suitable for golfing. <sup>(I hope there are no bugs in this interpreter, but I don't feel like testing it now.)</sup>

```js
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

// This interpreter implements GOTO-programs, which are Turing-complete.

var stdin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System['in']) );
var progsrc = stdin.readLine();
var prog = JSON.parse(progsrc).prog;

var vars = {};
vars.in = Number(stdin.readLine());

for(var i = 0; i < prog.length; i++) {
    switch(prog[i].command) {
        case 'ADD':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            vars[prog[i].varname] += prog[i].constant;
            break;
        case 'SUBSTRACT':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            vars[prog[i].varname] -= prog[i].constant;
            break;
        case 'GOTO':
            i = prog[i].index-1;
            break;
        case 'IF':
            vars[prog[i].varname] = vars[prog[i].varname] || 0;
            if(vars[prog[i].varname] == prog[i].constant) {
                i = prog[i].index-1;
            }
            break;
        case 'HALT':
            i = prog.length;
            break;
    }

    vars.out = vars.out || 0;
    print(vars.out);
}
```

Comment: What's the winning criterion?

Comment: @feersum Size of the JSON program. But nevermind. I realized how hard did I screw. Trivially, the correct solution is to pass the sole property name to an already-existant golfing language interpreter. I'll post a take 2 in a while...

Answer (score 0):

You have been given the following tree structure make from dictionaries and lists

```
{'snapshot': {'outer': {'inner': {'dir1': {'blob': 
          [{'file': '8ke45'}, {file1: '72d4kl'}]}, 
          'dir2': {'blob': [{'file1': 'fa65e'}]}}, 
           'something': {'blob': [{'thing1': '8447v'}]}}}
```

The dictionary contains all the directories and blobs(arbitrary file) in a given directory, in this case 'snapshot,' which contains the directory outer and no blobs. 'Outer' has all of its corresponding directories and blobs and so on until the end of the branch. Blobs objects are a dictionary with the key 'blob' and the value of a list of dictionaries containing the filename and content hash.

the tree looks like:

```
snapshot
    |_outer 
        |__ inner 
        |     |__dir1
        |     |   |__file
        |     |   |__file1
        |     |__dir2
        |     |   |__somefile
        |     |__another_file
        |__ something
            |__thing1
```

the objective to create trees files, wherein each directory is the hash of the hash of the underlying directories or blobs.

e.g the 'inner' file:

```
    name: 7j3429ds 
    contents: tree 8340dnwh28a          --di1
              tree sh2991ka86n          --dir2
              blob 12046bshs63          --anotherfile
```

You may hash the file using any known checksum ie. sha1, md5 ect. This is an example for the hash of the contents of a file:

```
def hash_(name):
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(bytes(str(name), encoding='utf-8'))
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    return(hex_dig)
```

---

An **Example** of the **final output** given the dictionary:

```
{'snapshot': {'inner': {'dir1':{'blob': [{'file': '8ke4528dgsk'}},  
                        'dir2': {'blob': [{'file1': 'fa65ek97n37'}]}}}
```

should look as such:

---

```
45334423112
    |_ds498kdh72b 
        |__ ak37ka729sm
        |     |__193bal7q8gl
        |__ o8pdn279ax8
              |__9y728s7ndsn
```

note the names of the files are just random hashes in the example when actually computing the hashes, the hash should consist of the hashes or all trees and blobs contained within that tree

45334423112 contents:

```
tree ds498kdh72b
```

ds498kdh72b contents:

```
tree ak37ka729sm
tree o8pdn279ax8
```

ak37ka729sm contents:

```
blob 8ke4528dgsk
blob fa65ek97n37
```

note that the blobs are the value of the filname key in the lowest level directory of the tree ie.

```
'dir1':{'blob': [{'file': '8ke4528dgsk'}]}
```

---

The winning criterion is the shortest solution.

If the question is seemingly vague, please comment on what you're unfamiliar with. Good luck ;)

Comment: would any which way mean returning the first character of the file name is fine? :P

Comment: "any way you want" is too open to abuse. `x => 0` is a valid hash function, just have a lot of collisions.

Comment: Cool thanks, very valid feedback :)

Comment: Your example has a mismatching `[`. (besides -- actually, the sandbox is relatively inactive, it's hard to get feedback)

Answer (score 0):

## Smallest Match-3 Game

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

I was reading about Match Three games, games about manipulating a field of symbols to generate lines of three or more matching symbols, and was thinking a playable game would be a pretty short program, if golfed.

The reason I think that is because it has less rules than Chess, so I thought that when golfed it'd be a simpler program shorter than the [Smallest chess program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45179/smallest-chess-program), which uses 487 bytes of Assembly, or less than 2 MB in any language used to answer that question.

Here's the other questions on this site, relating to Match-3 games:

- [Find the best immediate move in a "match-3" game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/find-the-best-immediate-move-in-a-match-3-game)
- [Determine if a move exists in a Bejeweled/match 3 game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26505/determine-if-a-move-exists-in-a-bejeweled-match-3-game)

Question:

**How small can a Match-3 Game Program be?**

**Rules**

- The symbols used can be any ones you want, just have at least 3 different symbols.
- At least a 4x4 board. Board size can be customized, if that's somehow easier.
- Board must start with a valid configuration, can stall player interaction and visibly reform the board, but player action must only be start to be allowed on a valid board.
- Any method of moving symbols is allowed. It could be sliding rows around, instead of swapping the positions of pieces, either side by side or anywhere on the board, or some other innovative way of moving pieces. But the board starts filled, and you move the symbols already there.
- Any method of selection of what to move is allowed.
- When a match happens, it's removed, and new pieces arrive, somehow. They don't have to fall from the top.
- It'd be nice if it could detect when there's no more valid moves.
- Random progression instead of deterministic would be nice as well.

### Sandbox Questions

Not sure how much variability in the end result I should have. I want to have maximum customization.

I suppose I could have the score for each entry be something like:

Bytes of code - average number of bytes used to implement each optional feature.

Comment: what is match-3?

Comment: Yeah, it would be good to have a short description of the game, to keep the question self-contained and make sure we're all on the same page. Also might be good to mention at the start that you're looking to golf a playable, interactive version of the game, and not a solver or anything like that (which is what I initially assumed).

Answer (score 0):

## Link the pairs of points

Given some pairs of points on a plane, connect each pair with a [simple polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain#Variations) such that any two different chains don't have any common points. The points won't necessarily be integral. Any two points in the input won't overlap.

Samples:

```
[{(0,1.2),(1,2)}] -> [{(0,1.2),(2.6,1),(1,2)}] # Output doesn't need to be optimized
[{(0,0),(1,1)},{(1,0),(0,1)}] -> [{(0,0),(1,1)},{(1,0),(9999,0),(0,999),(0,1)}]
```

Reasonable I/O method allowed. Code-golf, shortest code win.

Comment: I think you want to describe a [simple polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain).

Comment: Is there any two points in the input that have the same coordinate?

Comment: @user202729 The chain shouldn't intersect with itself and other chains

Comment: Is it a sufficient answer to sort the points by angle and join them all up in order, and if not why not?

Comment: @PeterTaylor You are to link each pair, not to link all of the points together

Answer (score 0):

Given some lists of strings containing only lowercase letters, slice the first few (1 to length) characters for each string in each list, so that when each list is joined without separating symbol, it can't be any other list's possible expression.

For example, for `{[ab,cd],[abcd]}`, `{ac,a}` is valid, but `{abc,a}` is not because `abc` can also mean `[abcd]`.

You can assume the result exist. If more than one solution, either output all of them or one of them. Shortest code win.

Answer (score 0):

## Shortest code to generate a random ethereum address with matching private key pair

[Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) is a blockchain platform.
An Ethereurem public address consist of 256 bytes based on ECDSA encryption.

It’s very simple challenge about a service available on many websites without registering (which most of the time involve going on website main page and click the generate button) : generate a random ethereum address !

#### What is an Ethereum address ?

An Ethereum address is a public/private key pair hence the public address is just the public part of the key pair. Here’s an example of Ethereum address with private key after :

```
0x7bbaf5E447B089C5e0a802d07A2bc63870e90f05 651bfdb66c839ae0aa4ed59bbada63c13876feb60a89ca6dacc63a7b04cf4b60
```

Every private key and [public key is valid](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) as long as the length above is the same. But you need to output a private key which match a public key (It’s possible to retrieve the public key from the private key).
Example online generators : https://vanity-eth.tk/ https://forkdelta.github.io https://etherdelta.com https://walletgenerator.net/

#### Example code to generate an address in bash :

```
#!/bin/sh

keys=$(openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout | openssl ec -text -noout 2> /dev/null)

# extract private key in hex format, removing newlines, leading zeroes and semicolon
priv=$(printf "%s\n" $keys | grep priv -A 3 | tail -n +2 | tr -d '\n[:space:]:' | sed 's/^00//')

# extract public key in hex format, removing newlines, leading '04' and semicolon
pub=$(printf "%s\n" $keys | grep pub -A 5 | tail -n +2 | tr -d '\n[:space:]:' | sed 's/^04//')

# sha3 is a subset of the keccak familly function. Thus keccak is included in most sha3 tools.
addr=0x$(echo $pub | keccak-256sum -x -l | tr -d ' -' | tail -c 41)

echo 'Private key:' $priv
echo 'Address:    ' $addr
```

### Rules

- The resulting public address shouldn’t be fully random : the last byte should be 0. This can be achieved by generating about 256 random address and selecting the first which has a trailing null byte (the probability is 1∕256).
- Print or return : the public key along the matching private key as a string.
- The solidity has native functions to generate an address, so you don’t have to understand how to generate an address

### Winner

The code which uses the fewest bytes.

Comment: Please explain what is unclear : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/165724/50239

Comment: `Fetching the result of an online generator though an HTTP request is valid if you can get a public key with 1 or several null bytes at the end.` Fetching results from an online source is usually a loophole forbidden by default. If you allow it here one could write their own generator which already handles the trailing zero requirement, put it on a website and post `curl <some link shortener>` as answer.

Comment: @Laikoni : yes. I’m accepting curl answers… What’s the problem. This question does it to : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152844/50239

Comment: The linked question explicitly states `Standard loopholes are obviously not allowed`, so I don't think that would be allowed. The general problem is that code-golf is about performing a certain task in the fewest number of bytes. Outsourcing the code which solves the task on a website and submitting code to the challenge which just gets the result from this page is thus generally not allowed, as your submitted code actually performs a different task, while the actual code that solves the task is not part of the score.

Comment: @Laikoni is it fixed now ?

Answer (score 0):

**Create random recurrences with their solutions**

(This is a work in progress and I would love any help please. First, how do I copy the wiki entry into this question without making a mess of the math as I have below? PPCG doesn't appear to support math rendering like the wiki does.)

The task is to create random recurrence relations that are solvable using the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) along with the solutions. This method solves recurrences of the form:

[image]

The conditions for usage are:

- sufficient base cases are provided
- a_i and b_i are constants for all i
- a_i > 0 for all i
- 0 < b_i < 1 for all i
- |g(x)| = O(x^c), where ''c'' is a constant and ''O'' notates [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
- | h_i(x) | = O(x/(log x)^2) for all i
- x_0 is a constant

The asymptotic behavior of T(x) is found by determining the value of p for which [image] and plugging that value into the equation

[image]

Comment: can you dumb this down so that people like me can understand it? maybe some examples?

Comment: @donbright Yes absolutely. I need to rewrite using Mathjax too now it is supported. I will work on it next week.

Comment: I have rewritten your post with code-golf delimited mathjax, here on pastebin:   https://pastebin.com/TLM4D0Ri

Answer (score 0):

## Divide two strings

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

One day, I saw the challenge to [multiply two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125470/multiply-two-strings) and I thought I might be able to do one better.

That challenge was fake. It was elementwise maximum. It was not real multiplication. So I set out to make something real. Real division between two strings.

I quickly realized that this would make an amazing challenge, as the algorithm was surprisingly complex and interesting to implement.

I then realized that it was actually easily reduced into a mere few operations. I'm still doing the challenge, though.

Enough with the backstory. Let's go.

### Method

To divide two strings, do the following, where `x` is the first string and `y` the second:

- If `x` does not contain `y`, return a space and a period concatenated to `x`.

  - For example, `testx` and `blah` would become `.textx`, with a space at the beginning.
- Otherwise, return every occurrence of `y` in `x`, a period, then `y` divided by `x` with every occurrence of `y` removed, with all the periods removed.

  - For example, `eestestst` and `est` would become `estest.est`.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that, given two strings via [standard input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), returns the first string divided by the second.

You may assume that neither input string contains a space, newline or period, and that the operation does not require more than 10 layers of recursion.

### Test cases

```
test, es => es. es
test, blah =>  .test
okayye, y => yy. y
testes, es => eses. es
battat, at => atat. at
see, es =>  .see
see, e => ee. e
same, same => same. 
aabb, ab => ab.ab 
eestestst, est => estest.est
aheahahe, aheah => aheah.aheah ah
```

### Scoring

As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the submission with the least amount of bytes wins.

## Sandbox questions

- Is this a duplicate?
- Have I missed anything?
- Does anything need further explaining?
- Is there an issue with the concept of the challenge?

Comment: What for `aabb / ab`?

Comment: `okayye, y => yy. okay` typo?

Comment: The test case `battat, at => atat. by` seems like it should be `battat, at => atat. bt` instead.

Comment: It seems odd to me that when no characters are matched the output format is `{matched characters (empty)}<space>.{unmatched characters}` while the format when there are matches becomes `{matched characters}.<space>{unmatched characters}`. I would much rather see consistent ordering of the `.` and `<space>`

Comment: @KamilDrakari 2 / 4 is 0.5, not .05, when 4 is not contained within 2 at all. Thus it makes no sense for test / blah to be `. test` when blah is not contained within test. We treat a space essentially like a zero would be with normal numbers.

Comment: @LyricLy 6/4 is 1.5 not 1.05. If you're treating space as 0 then there shouldn't be any space after the dot in any of the test cases.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Actually, you're right. I was entirely mistaken because you get a fraction from 1 / remainder, not original number / remainder. Meaning this entire thing is wrong and I need to figure out a good replacement for 1 in string form.

Comment: Fixed the issues.

Comment: I accept downvotes, but I'd appreciate suggestions on how to improve the idea, or at least an explanation of what's wrong with it, so I know why I shouldn't post it.

Comment: @LyricLy Please, post it if you haven't done it yet. It's so good!

Comment: @enzo This challenge [was posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166511/divide-two-strings).

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Often computers are used to perform consecutive jobs. Sometimes the order of doing these jobs does not matter. Other times there are dependencies between jobs that restrict the order that jobs can be performed. Additionally, jobs may require significant resources to store results, so it may be necessary to first schedule those jobs that will consume previous results before performing jobs that produce even more results. Furthermore, there may be significant costs to change from one type of job to another. The challenge then becomes finding the optimal execution order of jobs.

## Challenge

Allow me to illustrate the problem with an example. Consider a list of 10 jobs, numbered 0 to 9. Each of these jobs can be dependent on zero or more other jobs. (Assume there are no circular dependencies.) For example:

```
Job : Dependent on
---   ------------
0   : 8
1   : 6
2   :
3   : 0 6 9
4   : 7 9
5   : 2
6   : 4 8
7   :
8   : 9
9   :
```

This can be illustrated graphically as follows:

[image: Illustration]

One possible solution to this particular example is to perform the 10 jobs in the order: `9 8 7 4 6 0 2 1 3 5` While this solution satisfies the dependency requirements, it is not ideal. To see why, let us perform the jobs one at a time:

```
Job : Results stored in memory
---   ------------------------
9   : 9
8   : 8 9
7   : 7 8 9
4   : 4 8 9
6   : 6 8 9
0   : 0 6 9
2   : 0 2 6 9
1   : 0 1 2 6 9
3   : 1 2 3
5   : 1 3 5
```

After performing the first job (job 9), we only have the result of job 9 in memory. After performing job 8 we need to store the results of 8 and 9, and after job 7 we have the results of jobs 7, 8 and 9. After performing job 4 we find that the results of job 7 is no longer needed and we can discard that, leaving only the results of job 4, 8 and 9. Carrying on we find that the worst case memory usage is after job 1 when we have to store the results of 5 different jobs (0, 1, 2, 6 and 9).

As it turns out there is a better solution to this example, and that is to do the jobs in the order: `7 9 4 8 6 0 3 2 5 1` The memory usage is then:

```
Job : Results stored in memory
---   ------------------------
7   : 7
9   : 7 9
4   : 4 9
8   : 4 8 9
6   : 6 8 9
0   : 0 6 9
3   : 3 6
2   : 2 3 6
5   : 3 5 6
1   : 1 3 5
```

This time we only ever needed to store the results of 3 jobs in memory, instead of the 5 in the previous solution.

Finally, consider that each job is of a certain "type", and changing from one type to another is something that should be avoided. For example, let's say we have 3 types of jobs: A, B and C, and our 10 jobs in the example have the following types: Jobs 0-3 is type A, jobs 4-7 is type B, and jobs 8 and 9 is type C.

```
Job : Results stored in memory : Job Type Change
---   ------------------------ : ---------------
7   : 7                          B
9   : 7 9                        C
4   : 4 9                        B
8   : 4 8 9                      C
6   : 6 8 9                      B
0   : 0 6 9                      A
3   : 3 6                        .
2   : 2 3 6                      .
5   : 3 5 6                      B
1   : 1 3 5                      A
```

As you can see, we had to change the job type 8 times: `B C B C B A B A`

When minimizing job changes, while still keeping maximum memory usage to 3, we now find that the optimal solution is: `9 8 7 4 6 0 3 1 2 5`

```
Job : Results stored in memory : Job Type Change
---   ------------------------ : ---------------
9   : 9                          C
8   : 8 9                        .
7   : 7 8 9                      B
4   : 4 8 9                      .
6   : 6 8 9                      .
0   : 0 6 9                      A
3   : 3 6                        .
1   : 1 3                        .
2   : 1 2 3                      .
5   : 1 3 5                      B
```

This solution require only 4 job type changes (`C B A B`), while still only needing memory to store 3 results.

The solutions to this example that I presented here was found using a brute force search, ie going through every permutation of job order. From doing this I can tell you that this example has 1485 solutions that satisfy the dependency requirements. Of these 1485 solutions only 15 solutions require memory for no more than 3 results. Of these 15 solutions only 2 require only 4 job changes. The one is shown above (`9 8 7 4 6 0 3 1 2 5`). The other is: `9 8 7 4 6 0 3 2 1 5`.

Unfortunately, brute force is not viable when the total number of jobs increase beyond 10, eg 100. The challenge is to come up with an algorithm that can find the optimal solution (or any one of them if there are more than one) using an algorithm that significantly outperforms brute force.

## Example Input and Output

The input to the algorithm is a list of N jobs numbered 0 to N-1, each with a job type (A-Z) followed by a list of zero or more dependencies, eg:

```
0, A, 8
1, A, 6
2, A
3, A, 0 6 9
4, B, 7 9
5, B, 2
6, B, 4 8
7, B
8, C, 9
9, C
```

The output of the algorithm is the optimal execution order, eg:

```
9 8 7 4 6 0 3 1 2 5
```

Answers may be presented in any programming language or even pseudo code. I will translate them all to C++ and test them for correctness against the brute force algorithm using randomly generated inputs. The winner will be the algorithm that is fastest (and correct).

Comment: So, is this [tag:fastest-algorithm] or [tag:fastest-code]?

Comment: What if there is a solution with memory 2, job changes 3, and one with memory 3, job changes 2?  In other words, which one is given priority?

Comment: @wastl I think `fastest-code` would be the easiest because it might get difficult determining which is the `fastest-algorithm`. Least memory usage has a higher priority than least job changes.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

I want to do this, [Render an ASCII maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162403/render-an-ascii-maze) but with ascii pipe characters.
I know this is similar, but I think the extra logic required to figure out which character to put at each position makes this sufficiently different.

here is what I am thinking of asking.

Write code that replaces non whitespace characters in a string with ascii pipe characters depending on adjacency to other non-whitespace characters.
this will create something like a maze where non-whitespace characters are the walls, and whitespace is abscence of walls
here are the rules

your code should take its input from stdin and output to stdout

This table shows the correct output character for each combination of adjacent walls in directions: Left, Down, Up, and Right

```
 L D U R -> Output
 0 0 0 0 -> any non-whitespace character
 1 0 0 0 -> ─
 0 0 0 1 -> ─
 1 0 0 1 -> ─
 0 1 0 0 -> │
 0 0 1 0 -> │
 0 1 1 0 -> │
 1 1 0 0 -> ┐
 1 0 1 0 -> ┘
 0 1 0 1 -> ┌
 0 0 1 1 -> └
 1 1 1 0 -> ┤
 1 1 0 1 -> ┬
 1 0 1 1 -> ┴
 0 1 1 1 -> ├
 1 1 1 1 -> ┼
```

if characters are on the edge of a string then they should treat the outside as whitespace

This will be a code golf challenge

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80634/194 ?

Comment: I didn't see that one, but I still think this is different, because this does not require specific characters as input, the input can be any string

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Comment: Although there are some minor differences, this was probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: i'll try to think of something to make this one different

Answer (score 0):

### *N* represented with only `1`s in any base from 2 to *N-2*?

> This is mostly a less interesting special case of [Repdigit Base Finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75623/194) so I won't submit.

Any positive integer *N* can be expressed as `11` in base *N-1* or as *N* concatenated `1`s in base 1. Let's call those the ***trivial*** cases in which *N* can be represented using only `1`s. Let's call any other "all `1`s" representation ***non-trivial***. Some examples:

- 7 has an "all `1`s" representation in base 2, so 7 has a ***non-trivial*** "all `1`s" representation.
- 16 has ***no non-trivial*** "all `1`s" representation.
- 11 itself has ***no non-trivial*** "all `1`s" representation by my definition because it is "all `1`s" in base 10, which is 11-1.

### Challenge

Provide a program/function that produces one of two distinct, consistent values for whether or not an integer *N* > 3 has a non-trivial "all `1`s" representation in a base between 2 and *N-2*.

Comment: I was thrown off by the 11 example, because there is quite clearly a way to express that using only `1`, but then I realized that it's trivial because base 10 is base n-1 in that situation. That might be a good note to add.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##bVFdb4JAEHzmfsXGNOaIlGDtG0habdI00bRJSfvCCx@nXoKH5Q7UGH673TuptR8hsCwzO8zOZfI6k9mxllws4XUvFVu707IoWKZ4KaT7yASreOaTS8bPzp1x8eEfsyKREjYHqRLFM2hKnsM84YLaBzJFqbJg7nvFFUM6o723pKhZrB74kisZq0kiWSx6tk9mXKogqjcFC7hQTneHITR6QsIYBNvCLxZ8PcKQosairIBiBznSRz6WAIYe1sEA3ZzRFNEbH0sAt4imBrU00iASldpUxATNHUhR1eIL2hglz4N@H0kheDaxrJMz9z7Pqfb2ny3aOLmT2qjS4nUaGHdzz1XOqsme7mAcws59wkyHthuVesduG5ZkK9oklQ4B9bosbIJ2/2Z71TsgftJpY3Vubi6bUdvrzJDuxPTe3zub9MzhmAXgLkXA/FB3sl5jQh5mcg6Tmw9Ygm4O3zFQYuGIpfmDsSHa80St3JdyS40kqutoW2JVTNWV0NLaF2mPx08) should generate the truthy numbers up to 1000

Comment: @KamilDrakari very nice, thanks. I wonder how many numbers have more than one such base (like 31)? That's an entirely different challenge.

Comment: I updated the code to search for duplicates, but could only find `31` and `8191`. [Golfed to fit the link in a comment](https://tio.run/##VZBNb8IwDIb/ioV2SASL2DiGIq0c0DQ2TdqByy5p4kGkkrB88CHU396loRNwsv3Gfu0n0j9KL9votVnD18kH3LK5rWuUQVvj2QINOi35bcNdwZba/N4rH3HbzXjeylp4D7uzDyJoCXurFbwLbQg974WDvagj@sLgAZbah2mp168m4BrdjFD@Yx3RJoAqJlxNJ@MxV8Mh/Ver4plXWa2SenFiL0qRkqhRRSnvFqi4q7UUIS3pOxbOxl15IsdidqRstUGHOU/Q0QRCZ095MQq5If2JoM2NEZ2nb7E1spXTARM8kodBoqnZG56a75DT3qwZUN707Fc2KC9YI8gc9Hzz5OMWChh3J0Du0rlMYQoqhYSaWobFdYR92gOpkhflDkN0pvPgTdO2fw)

Comment: Table seems wrong

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75623/194 .

Comment: Note that these are numbers of the form `(b**x - 1) / (b-1)` for integer `b > 1` and integer `x > 2`.

Comment: Also: [OEIS A053696](http://oeis.org/A053696). Either your reference implementation was broken or you didn't remove duplicates.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you for alerting me to the other challenge, which is close enough for me to say this one is a dupe (at least and easier and less interesting special case.)

Comment: Thanks for using the Sandbox!

Answer (score 0):

## # Proposed Question # [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## List the amount of factors for a given number.

### For Example:

If given 1936, the output should be 15 (as 1936 has 15 factors)
If given 196, the output should be 9 (as 196 has 9 factors)

### Test cases:

- 64 - Outputs 7
- 196 - Outputs 9
- 1936 - Outputs 15

### Scoring:

Code Golf - Least number of bytes for each language wins (No answer)

I have made my own in JavaScript - 143 Bytes. 
 Available here: https://glot.io/snippets/f1tl0vrnmy

 To use different numbers, change the `console.log(f(64).length)` to `console.log(f(###).length)` where `###` is your desired number.
 BTW, if JavaScript or similar, only the defining function is considered in code length. The method of outputting (eg. console.log) does not count.

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm not a native speaker, but isn't that called "divisor" (not factor)?

Comment: I fear it would get closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104590/80010)

Comment: [Exact duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64944/count-the-divisors-of-a-number).

Comment: @wastl depends which country you are in (America or the rest of the world).

Comment: @JayCe i don't think so the, as that is the *prime factorisation* of the number, where i am asking for the factor count. But, as with **user202729**, it is an exact duplicate. So, Thanks guys :D

Comment: Thanks for using the Sandbox :)

Answer (score 0):

## Block partite a string

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Inspiration](https://szkopul.edu.pl/problemset/problem/t5FLaUejqAvkMfX7RnLzfEI_/site).

Consider a list `l`, consisting of numbers. Define a block operation at index `i` on the list `l` to be the act of moving 3 consecutive elements starting from `i` in `l` to the end.

Example:

```
l, i (1-indexing) -> l (after applying block operation at index i)
[1,2,3,4,5], 1 -> [4,5,1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3 -> [1,2,6,7,3,4,5]
```

Given a list consisting of only 0 and 1, your challenge is to partite it so that zeros are at the front, and ones are at the back, using only block operations. Output should be the indices in the order they are applied on the list.

Because this is impossible for the list `[1,0,1,0]`, the list length is guaranteed to be at least 5.

Also (as a bonus, to avoid handling special cases) there is at least 5 ones and 5 zeroes.

## Test cases (1-indexing)

(there are other valid outputs)

```
[1,1,1,0,0] -> [1]
[0,1,0,1,0] -> [1,2,1,1]
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0] -> [4]
```

Use [this script](https://tio.run/##y/r/vygxLyU/N744NTXFVs/QyNjE1IwrLz41JzUXyDXg4rJUtDI2V9AwUIgHQU0Q31ABSRNXanJGvoK9AkSPstH//wA) to generate more test cases. (only input)

## Winning criteria

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.
Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting your solution. Try to come up with as short as possible solution for *any* language.

## Note

- [[atomic-code-golf] variant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166353/69850).
- You're free to brute force, although I expect that a non-brute-force solution would be much shorter.

Comment: @HatWizard This is the code-golf variant, I'm sure that I didn't post it. The other one is atomic-code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Most times a loop

Given a positive integer `n`. For an array of length `n`, each two element of which are different, repeatedly rearrange it using the same permutation till it's the same as original. How many times was the array rearranged at most?

Samples:

```
input output example permutation
1     1      [a1]
2     2      [a2 a1]
3     3      [a3 a1 a2]
4     4      [a4 a1 a2 a3]
5     6      [a3 a1 a2 a5 a4]
```

Comment: Must the permutation be outputted, or only the number of steps?

Comment: @user202729 only the one number

Comment: In short: Given a number `n`, what is the largest [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of an [element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)) in a [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on `n` letters?

Comment: You might want to clarify that the input is the length of the array. Since the question starts "Given an array", I assumed the input was an array and was confused at first. (I think it needs more elaboration in general too.)

Comment: @sundar problem edited; what if given an array where some elements may be same? (maybe turns into another problem)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000793

Comment: can you show the steps of doing a permutation? for dumb dumbs like me?

Answer (score 0):

**DayByte Savings**

Input: Any positive integer 1..n; or a year in the future (e.g. `2025`)

Output: The date-times (UTC) that Britain will change to/from daylight savings times (i.e. 1am on the last Sunday in March and 2am on the last Sunday in October) between now (according to the machine running the code) and the current date in the year specified in the input. We can assume this rule won't change in the future.

Any valid list of date-time formats is fine for the output (e.g. "28th October 2018 2am" or "28-OCT-18T02:00:00" or "1540692000" [epoch time])

inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839863/future-list-of-daylight-savings-changeover-date-times-uk

You could store all the data in your program (it counts towards your byte count), or just call a builtin that calculates it - your choice.

You can assume that 2099 (however far ahead that is) is the largest input.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), usual rules and exclusions apply. You won't have to deal with invalid inputs.

Example (assuming today is 23rd September 2019):

```
2020 or 1 -> 27th Oct 2019 2am; 29th Mar 2020 1am

2099 or 80 -> 27 October 2019 02:00:00
      29 March 2020 01:00:00
      25 October 2020 02:00:00
      28 March 2021 01:00:00
      31 October 2021 02:00:00
      27 March 2022 01:00:00
      30 October 2022 02:00:00
      26 March 2023 01:00:00
      29 October 2023 02:00:00
      31 March 2024 01:00:00
      27 October 2024 02:00:00
      30 March 2025 01:00:00
      26 October 2025 02:00:00
      29 March 2026 01:00:00
      25 October 2026 02:00:00
      28 March 2027 01:00:00
      31 October 2027 02:00:00
      26 March 2028 01:00:00
      29 October 2028 02:00:00
      25 March 2029 01:00:00
      28 October 2029 02:00:00
      31 March 2030 01:00:00
      27 October 2030 02:00:00
      30 March 2031 01:00:00
      26 October 2031 02:00:00
      28 March 2032 01:00:00
      31 October 2032 02:00:00
      27 March 2033 01:00:00
      30 October 2033 02:00:00
      26 March 2034 01:00:00
      29 October 2034 02:00:00
      25 March 2035 01:00:00
      28 October 2035 02:00:00
      30 March 2036 01:00:00
      26 October 2036 02:00:00
      29 March 2037 01:00:00
      25 October 2037 02:00:00
      28 March 2038 01:00:00
      31 October 2038 02:00:00
      27 March 2039 01:00:00
      30 October 2039 02:00:00
      25 March 2040 01:00:00
      28 October 2040 02:00:00
      31 March 2041 01:00:00
      27 October 2041 02:00:00
      30 March 2042 01:00:00
      26 October 2042 02:00:00
      29 March 2043 01:00:00
      25 October 2043 02:00:00
      27 March 2044 01:00:00
      30 October 2044 02:00:00
      26 March 2045 01:00:00
      29 October 2045 02:00:00
      25 March 2046 01:00:00
      28 October 2046 02:00:00
      31 March 2047 01:00:00
      27 October 2047 02:00:00
      29 March 2048 01:00:00
      25 October 2048 02:00:00
      28 March 2049 01:00:00
      31 October 2049 02:00:00
      27 March 2050 01:00:00
      30 October 2050 02:00:00
      26 March 2051 01:00:00
      29 October 2051 02:00:00
      31 March 2052 01:00:00
      27 October 2052 02:00:00
      30 March 2053 01:00:00
      26 October 2053 02:00:00
      29 March 2054 01:00:00
      25 October 2054 02:00:00
      28 March 2055 01:00:00
      31 October 2055 02:00:00
      26 March 2056 01:00:00
      29 October 2056 02:00:00
      25 March 2057 01:00:00
      28 October 2057 02:00:00
      31 March 2058 01:00:00
      27 October 2058 02:00:00
      30 March 2059 01:00:00
      26 October 2059 02:00:00
      28 March 2060 01:00:00
      31 October 2060 02:00:00
      27 March 2061 01:00:00
      30 October 2061 02:00:00
      26 March 2062 01:00:00
      29 October 2062 02:00:00
      25 March 2063 01:00:00
      28 October 2063 02:00:00
      30 March 2064 01:00:00
      26 October 2064 02:00:00
      29 March 2065 01:00:00
      25 October 2065 02:00:00
      28 March 2066 01:00:00
      31 October 2066 02:00:00
      27 March 2067 01:00:00
      30 October 2067 02:00:00
      25 March 2068 01:00:00
      28 October 2068 02:00:00
      31 March 2069 01:00:00
      27 October 2069 02:00:00
      30 March 2070 01:00:00
      26 October 2070 02:00:00
      29 March 2071 01:00:00
      25 October 2071 02:00:00
      27 March 2072 01:00:00
      30 October 2072 02:00:00
      26 March 2073 01:00:00
      29 October 2073 02:00:00
      25 March 2074 01:00:00
      28 October 2074 02:00:00
      31 March 2075 01:00:00
      27 October 2075 02:00:00
      29 March 2076 01:00:00
      25 October 2076 02:00:00
      28 March 2077 01:00:00
      31 October 2077 02:00:00
      27 March 2078 01:00:00
      30 October 2078 02:00:00
      26 March 2079 01:00:00
      29 October 2079 02:00:00
      31 March 2080 01:00:00
      27 October 2080 02:00:00
      30 March 2081 01:00:00
      26 October 2081 02:00:00
      29 March 2082 01:00:00
      25 October 2082 02:00:00
      28 March 2083 01:00:00
      31 October 2083 02:00:00
      26 March 2084 01:00:00
      29 October 2084 02:00:00
      25 March 2085 01:00:00
      28 October 2085 02:00:00
      31 March 2086 01:00:00
      27 October 2086 02:00:00
      30 March 2087 01:00:00
      26 October 2087 02:00:00
      28 March 2088 01:00:00
      31 October 2088 02:00:00
      27 March 2089 01:00:00
      30 October 2089 02:00:00
      26 March 2090 01:00:00
      29 October 2090 02:00:00
      25 March 2091 01:00:00
      28 October 2091 02:00:00
      30 March 2092 01:00:00
      26 October 2092 02:00:00
      29 March 2093 01:00:00
      25 October 2093 02:00:00
      28 March 2094 01:00:00
      31 October 2094 02:00:00
      27 March 2095 01:00:00
      30 October 2095 02:00:00
      25 March 2096 01:00:00
      28 October 2096 02:00:00
      31 March 2097 01:00:00
      27 October 2097 02:00:00
      30 March 2098 01:00:00
      26 October 2098 02:00:00
      29 March 2099 01:00:00
```

Comment: p.s. how do people add formatted tags to answers?

Comment: `[tag:<name>]`, e.g. `[tag:code-golf]` (in comments, it looks like [tag:code-golf])

Comment: You can click at the "edited..." link and click "source" to view markdown source.

Comment: Should the output be accurate to the date the challenge is posted, the date a solution is posted or the date that solution is run? Or, to put it another way, if I post a solution now it should, obviously, include `27/10/19` in the output but, if that solution is run *after* that date, should it still be included?

Comment: My thinking is, the date the challenge is run (i.e. whatever date is set on the machine the code is run on)

Comment: Would this challenge be better if it was just "print the next time after "today" on your local system"? or "print the next time after the input date"?

Answer (score 0):

## Which number nearest?

We say 2018 is near 2000, but not 2018 is near 2030, though |2030-2018|<|2000-2018|. Given some pairs of numbers (a,b) and two numbers g>0 and x, find an x+t for min((|t|<sup>c</sup>+g)*b<sup>d</sup>) for t as a real number making (x+t) mod a = 0, (a,b) as one of the pairs. You can decide `c` to be 1 or 2, and `d` to be 1 or -1, as long as it's constant.

Samples: (c=1, d=1)

```
In: {(1000, 1), (10, 100)}, g=1, x=2018
Out: 2000

In: {(1000, 1), (10, 1)}, g=1, x=2018
Out: 2020

In: {(1, 1), (10, 1)}, g=1, x=2018
Out: 2018
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I think this is an interesting challenge, but you really need some nicely formatted formulas here. The plain-text forms are hardly readable.

Comment: @Adám MathJax is currently not supported.

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't we say 2018 is near 2030? It seems grammatically fine to me.

Comment: @JoKing 2030 is not that integer, and saying it near another strange number is quite meaningless

Comment: Sorry? I think there's a language barrier here. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I guess the intent is to find the nearest *round* number, with the (a,b) pairs deciding what a "round number" is. I agree that better formatting would help with readability, and more importantly some explanation text: what is `c`, what is `d`, what does `g`'s value affect, and in general how did the `min((|t|c+g)*bd)` formula come about?

Answer (score 0):

## Is there a dangling else?

Define a statement as follows (Backus-Naur form) (based on Java syntax):

```
statement ::= ";"
  | "if(true)" <statement>
  | "if(true)" <statement> "else " <statement>
```

Example valid statements:

```
;
if(true);else ;
if(true);else if(true);else ;
```

Example invalid statement that is valid Java syntax, but considered invalid for simplicity:

```
if(false);
if(true);else;
if(1>0);else ;
System.out.println("This is invalid");
```

Your task is, given a valid statement, determine if it contains a dangling else (that is, it can be parsed into more than one ways)

#### Test cases

**Truthy test cases** (contains a dangling else)

Presented in the format `{input}¶ -> {parse 1}¶ -> {parse 2}`

```
if(true)if(true);else ;
 -> if(true){if(true);}else ;
 -> if(true){if(true);else ;}

if(true)if(true);else if(true);else ;
 -> if(true){if(true);else if(true);}else ;
 -> if(true){if(true);}else{if(true);else ;}

if(true);else if(true);else if(true)if(true);else ;
 -> if(true);else if(true);else if(true){if(true);}else ;
 -> if(true);else if(true);else if(true){if(true);else ;}
```

**Falsy test cases** (uniquely parsed)

```
if(true)if(true)if(true);
if(true)if(true);else ;else ;
if(true);else if(true);else if(true);else ;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Quine of Hanoi

### Objetive

Make a program that print a rearranged version of itself

### Rules

- Your program will consist of newlines and 3 blocks : `A`, `B` and `C` where each block will have distinct and nonzero lengths, i.e. `0 < length(A) < length(B) < length(C)`.
- The output will be based on the order of the code blocks and newlines,
  it will be a new arrangement that progresses toward a solved state by one move unless it is already solved, following [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) rules.

For example:

```
CA
B
```

Will print

```
C
B
A
```

### Additional rules

- Your program don't have to handle invalid orders, e.g. `CAB`
- You have to handle at least one configuration of each group (but not necessarily all of them).
- The order of the lines is irrelevant.

For example

```
CA
B
```

CAN print

```
B
C
A
```

### Examples

```
#Group 0 - will output itself
CBA

#Group 1 - will output one of group 0
A\nCB
CB\nA

#Group 2 - will output one of group 1
A\nB\nC
A\nC\nB
B\nA\nC
B\nC\nA
C\nA\nB
C\nB\nA

#Group 3 - will output one of group 2
CA\nB
B\nCA
```

### Winning

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the one with the shortest code (`A`+`B`+`C`) wins

Comment: To me, this seems like a "challenge rules inferred from test cases" situation. Specifically, it seems that the desired behavior is "when the code is run, it outputs a new arrangement that *progresses toward a solved state* by one move unless it is already solved", but you just say "follow Tower of Hanoi rules".

Comment: @KamilDrakari indeed, can I use your description in the challenge?

Comment: I don't mind, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

## The Shifty Maze

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [python3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3)

---

You are a wild mouse and you have stumbled on a maze that some human has constructed to observe your behavior. The maze is littered with blobs of peanut butter and has a cache of sunflower seeds near its center. After discovering the seeds, you decide that you want to take them all home to your personal cache. You must find your way to the seeds and exit the maze. Since there are so many seeds, it takes you many trips to get them all.

Things go well your first time. You find your way to the seeds, bring a few back, and return to the maze. To your surprise, when you return the second time, the maze looks nothing like it did before, but you quickly figure out that the entrance was simply in a different place and continue navigating as usual. The next time you return to the maze, you are once again lost, but you find a familiar pattern of peanut butter dabs and find your way to the sunflower seeds once again. Naturally, you catch onto this pattern and eventually retrieve all the sunflower seeds.

## The Challenge

Your task is to make a "mouse" bot that navigates through a maze where the entrance moves to somewhere else on the edge of the maze every time you exit and enter it. You have no limits on memory, but no absolute sense of direction and a limited visual field. You can only exit the maze after finding the cache. Your goal is to get all of the seeds in as few steps as possible.

### Mazes

A [perfect maze](https://www.google.com/search?q=perfect%20maze%20definition) is randomly generated using a randomized version of [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Randomized_Prim's_algorithm) starting from a cell near the center. The seed cache will be close to the center. 10% of the cells will be dabbed with 3-5 units of peanut butter. There will not be any peanut butter on the same cell as the seed cache. The maze used for scoring will be 30x30 cells.

### Actions

Each turn, you can move forward or turn 90 degrees in either direction. If there is any peanut butter on your current cell, you may also eat one unit of it instead of moving or turning. (Partially eaten peanut butter can be used to create landmarks for navigation.)

### Vision

You can see every cell in a straight line in front of you until a wall obstructs your view. You can also see one cell to your left and right, provided there is no wall between that cell and your current cell.

For each cell that you can see, you can see whether there is a wall on each of the four edges of the cell, how much peanut butter is on that cell, and whether it is the seed cache or the exit.

#### Example

Suppose you had this maze:

```
+-----+-------+-+---+
|     |  5    | |   |
| ----+-- +---+ | --+
|4    |   |@   3    |
| --+-+ --+---- | --+
|   | |    4   <|   |
| --+ | --+ | | +-+ |
|         | | |   | |
| | +-- --+-+ +-- +-+
| | |    3  | |     |
+-+-+-------+-+ ----+
```

`@` is the seed cache. Numbers are blobs of peanut butter. `<` is the mouse (facing west)

The vision for the mouse would look something like this:

```
  +-+

  + +
  | |
  + +    
   4|
  + +
    |
+-+ + +
|.(^)3
+ +-+ +
```

### No memory limit

You can remember as little or as much as you would like. The challenge is in figuring out where you are as quickly as possible and reduce the amount of time you spend wandering.

## Test Driver

The test driver can be found [here](https://github.com/Beefster09/pcg-general/blob/master/shifty.py).

## Coding

Your solution should be compatible with Python 3.7. You should implement a class with the following methods:

- A constructor taking no arguments
- `get_action`, which is called with one argument representing your vision on each step of navigation (more on that below). This should return a string representing the action to take: `forward`, `left`, `right`, or `eat` are valid values. If this returns an action that cannot be taken, an exception will be thrown and your solution will be considered invalid.
- `enter_maze`, which is called without arguments each time the maze is entered. No return value is expected and the function doesn't actually have to do anything. The next time `get_action` is called, you are guaranteed to be on the cell on the edge of the maze facing away from the entrance/exit.

### The Vision Object

You will receive an object with the following attributes:

- `left` and `right`: the cells to your left and right. If there is a wall that obstructs your view, this will be `'???'` instead of the cell view object.
- `forward`: a list of all the cells in your forward vision, starting with your current cell and continuing until the last cell in your vision.

Any of these cell views may also be `None`, indicating the entrance/exit of the maze.

Each visible cell inside the maze will be an object with the following attributes:

- `forward`, `left`, `right`, `back`: booleans indicating whether there is a wall in the given directions, oriented the same way as the mouse.
- `contents`: an integer representing the amount of peanut butter (if any), None (if nothing is on the cell), or 'cache' if the cell contains the seed cache.

## Scoring and Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.

  - If your bot only works on the scoring maze, it is an invalid solution. Your bot does not receive enough input to distinguish the scoring maze from another maze, so hard-coding a route will produce an invalid solution.
- Run the test driver to score your result. It uses an isolated and seeded random number generator to ensure that all entries get the same maze and sequence of entrances. The total number of turns it took to retrieve all of the seeds (this takes 100 iterations through the maze) is your score.
- Include your score, your code, and an explanation in your solution post.
- You must output a valid move each turn. Moving into a wall or attempting to eat nonexistent peanut butter will result in an error that you have no opportunity to recover from.
- You may not exit the maze until you have visited the cell containing the seed cache since the last time you entered the maze.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that when `enter_maze` is called, the mouse is on an edge of the maze?

Comment: @user202729 I should clarify that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

## Rotational symmetry in which bases from 2 to 36

A number (here, a non-negative integer) is rotationally symmetric if it "looks" the same after being rotated 180 degrees. For example, `69` (heh.) 
 [Here's a related challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77866/numbers-with-rotational-symmetry)

We're going to consider bases from 2 to 36, using the symbols `0-9A-Z` as the digits. We're going to be generous with what digits are rotationally similar. Each of the following pairs will qualify (order not relevant):

```
00, 11, 22, 55, 69, 88, B8, D0, DD, E3, I1, L7, S5, SS, Z2, XX, ZZ
```

#### The challenge

Given a non-negative integer `n` in base 10, write a program or function that produces a list of bases from 2 to 36 in which the `n` is rotationally symmetric.

#### Input and output

Any reasonable input format is allowed (the integer itself, its character representation, an array of digits, an array of digits as characters.)

Any output format that communicates the desired result in an unambiguous way is acceptable. For example, a 35 element array of truthy/falsey values. If it's easier to include base 1 (always truthy) that's fine too.

#### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Fewest bytes in each language. Usual rules apply.

Comment: Why take input in base 10? I don't think it would make it too easy to take input in other bases ...

Comment: this is fun, but are there examples? im a bit slow on the uptake

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge

### n=2πr

Given an input, n, print a circle with the circumference of n characters.

## Rules

- The characters for the circumference of the circle can be any non-whitespace character
- Shapes don't have to be an amazing circle, kinda roundish shapes are still valid
- The circle can have a small gap, but no overlap

## Examples

```
Input: 1
Output:
o

Input: 2
Output:
oo

Input: 3
Output:
oo
o

Input: 7
Output:
 ooo
o   o
 oo

Input: 20
Output:
  oooooo
 o      o
o        o
o        o
 o      o    
  oooooo
```

Comment: Objective valid criteria please?

Comment: (BTW SE won't allow you to post a title with <15 chars. NBSP and some ZWSP can reduce it to 7, but no less.)

Comment: Also, most languages will suffer from the floating inaccuracy of \$\pi\$ or trigonometric functions (\$\sin\$ or \$\cos\$), so you should say "although theorically it must work for all input, in practice your program only need to work with \$n\le1000\$ (or some other bounds)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! The valid criteria is a very valid point, i'm working on making my own solution right now so I have something I can give to reproduce. I am aware of the title limit, I'm trying to come up with a better title before it is posted. And I will think about the inaccuracy of pi, because that could cause some headaches.
Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Shortest code to send an html s/mime signed message with one attachment over smtps

Simple challenge : use a valid RSA based security certificate in order to sign message [according to s/mime rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751) and send it over smtp over TLS on port 465 (or starttls on port 25).

### Rules :

- The program parameters takes an ʜᴛᴍʟ string consisting of message body ; a message subject as string ; a sender address as string ; and list of recipients address.
  They can be obtained either as function/class parameters or program arguments or read from keyboard input.
- The security certificate is read from an hardcoded file name of your choice or a hardcoded non empty string.
  It can be in the format of your choice.
- The attachment is read is read from an hardcoded file name of your choice or 2 non empty hardcoded strings (1 for filepath and the other 1 for content)
- [The s/mime signing rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751) state that message body should be signed and other part shoudln’t be signed, this means in practice that data stating the message is in the html format and all data about attachments should be signed (subject priority, and e‑mail addresses aren’t signed).
- When I say you have free choice, just pick up the solution using the fewest bytes.

### Winner

The code which uses the fewest bytes.

Comment: I dont understand, what's the point in giving both the filepath and the content? Is the content enough?

Comment: @user202729 Inside e‑mail data, a valid attachment consists of a file path and it’s data. Otherwise, does the question looks Ok ?

Comment: One problem with this type of "minimal code to do a task over a protocol" question is that it's not clear how much of the protocol must be implemented. E.g. should the client handle grey-listing?

Answer (score 0):

## Earth mover's distance [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Dupe check: Do we already have a challenge about the [Earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)? 
Some possibilities could be to compute it for a 1D array, a 2D array, or a circle.

Comment: Not as such, but it's basically just linear programming so you'd want to avoid creating a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156287/194 . I don't recall any non-integer linear programming questions; the technique has been used in some KotH answers, but I think they encode the solution rather than the solver.

Answer (score 0):

## Fewest instructions to copy bytes in memory in WebAssembly.

Implement the functionality for copying bytes in memory in WebAssembly.

### Rules

- Use WebAssembly, written in [wast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format) (the text format).
- Any of the WebAssembly [instructions](https://webassembly.org/docs/semantics) are fine.
- In calling copy, it doesn't need to worry about overriding an existing string.
- Doesn't need to worry about the strings being too large to fit into memory, strings will be reasonable size and wont overflow over the end. For example, the total memory is 10000 bytes, so strings might be 100 bytes and only go to 5000 in the memory. (But those aren't actual hardcodable values).
- No calling JavaScript functions.
- The string "Hello World" starts of at position 0 in memory. Copy this string to random places in memory and log it, as shown in the xample below.

The winning answer is the one with the *fewest WebAssembly instructions*. That is, feel free to have a functions in WebAssembly, just no calling or importing JavaScript functions.

### Example

To get started, here is the start of the WebAssembly module:

```
// example.wast
(module
  (memory (export "mem") 1)
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello World")
  ;; instructions counting starts from here:
  (func (export "copy")
    (param i32) ;; existing start index
    (param i32) ;; size in bytes
    (param i32) ;; new index to copy to
    ...))
```

And here is how to load it, as well as the tests:

```
// example.js
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('example.wasm'), {}).then(mod => {
  var exports = mod.instance.exports
  var i8 = new Uint8Array(exports.mem)
  var i = 200 + rand(500)
  exports.copy(0, 11, i)
  var i2 = 1000 + rand(500)
  exports.copy(i, 11, i2)
  console.log(i, getString(i, 11))
  console.log(i2, getString(i2, 11))

  function rand(size) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (size + 1))
  }

  function getString(index, size) {
    var string = ''
    for (var i = index; i < index + size; i++) {
      string += String.fromCharCode(i8[i])
    }
    return string
  }
})
```

### Resources

Potentially useful resources:

- [Memory in WebAssembly (and why it’s safer than you think)](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/07/memory-in-webassembly-and-why-its-safer-than-you-think/)
- [Example of the `.data` section in wast](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/bca1718f6a974453c0e35df94b220bd83cc85be8/test/core/data.wast#L5-L19)
- [Example `func` in WebAssembly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/bca1718f6a974453c0e35df94b220bd83cc85be8/test/core/func.wast)
- [Example of WebAssembly iteration with `block`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/bca1718f6a974453c0e35df94b220bd83cc85be8/test/core/block.wast)
- [WebAssembly examples](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/bca1718f6a974453c0e35df94b220bd83cc85be8/test/core)

Comment: It's been a few days, wondering if I could post this :)

Comment: Limiting this challenge to wast only will probably result in this question not going over well with the people on this stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

## Concatenate my strings!

As you know, we all like to save bytes around here. So, my strings are special: they come in four different flavours depending on the highest code point in the string:

- ASC (code points up to 0x7F). Like ISO but all bytes have values less than 0x80.
- ISO (code points up to 0xFF). Each byte represents a code point.
- UTF (code points up to 0x7FF). Uses UTF-8 encoding.
- UCS (code points up to 0xFFFF). Uses UCS-2 encoding.

For input you will receive two strings, each represented by a flavour identifier and a sequence of bytes representing the code points according to the flavour. You then need to output a byte sequence using the best flavour to hold the concatenation. Except where limited by standard loopholes, you don't need to use the designations ASC, ISO, UTF and UCS, so for instance if you choose to use numbers 0-3 for the flavours then the output flavour is simply the maximum of the two input flavours.

Example:

```
ISO 43 6F 64 65 A0 + ASC 47 6F 6C 66 = ISO 43 6F 64 65 A0 47 6F 6C 66
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function wins!

Comment: how do you define the best flavor for concatenation? im guessing 'shortest'... but it would help to say it. also maybe a few more examples?

Comment: @donbright "depending on the highest code point in the string"

Comment: @donbright You can do it depending on the highest code point, but you can just assume the highest code point of the input strings given their flavour if it's easier.

Comment: oh i get it now. thanks. i like this.

Comment: Well, I still don't get it - (1) why do you say "code points up to 0x7FF" for UTF-8? UTF-8 can encode codepoints up to 10FFFF. Do you mean some byte-limited variant of UTF-8? (2) except for UTF-8, it seems the task is just to choose the higher encoding ("maximum of the two input flavours" as you say), and possibly add `00` prefix bytes if output flavour is UCS-2. Is UTF-8 intended to be the main part of the challenge? Or am I missing something? (More examples and test cases would probably help by the way.)

Comment: @sundar Because `U+0800` takes 3 bytes in UTF-8 but only 2 in UCS-2, I'm pretending that I'm choosing the golfiest encoding for the bytes... I didn't want the challenge to get bogged down in the detail of choosing which encoding was best for a given string. Also, `00` suffix bytes only helps for some of the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

## Count binomial coefficient entries

This task is very simple. For integer \$n \ge 0 \$, given the binomial coefficients of all the expansions of \$ (x+y)^m \$ for \$ 0 \le m \le n \$, count the number of occurrences of \$ n \$. This is OEIS [A003016](http://oeis.org/A003016).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## An example text for scrambled-words experiment. Version 1

### Introduction

This challenge is based on an old experiment that proves that we only need first two and last two letters in order to uniquely identify a word. The remaining middle-characters can be completely scrambled and yet we should not have any problems in reading the whole word. And the speed of reading even longest scrambled-words based text shouldn't be significantly longer than reading an "normal" text.

The challenge itself is to write a shortest possible code (any language) that can be used to generate test texts to prove above described idea.

The experiment in the background of this challenge was conducted many years ago by some English or American scientist. I can't credit particular source or recall any other details. The challenge itself is created by me.

### Challenge

Write the shortest possible code to generate test text (any length) based on following algorithm:

1. For each word in input text.

   - If word is 5 characters long or less -- keep it unchanged.
   - If word is 6 characters long or longer -- keep first two and last two characters unchanged and scramble remaining ones.
2. Print generated resulting text with scrambled words.

There there no corner cases except for two assumptions:

1. Words with 5 characters and less should be kept untouched.
2. Your code must support all UTF-8 characters, not just English / non-Latin alphabet.

I assume "standard" approach here, so the winner of the challenge will be determined by the length of the code.

### Example Input and Output

Input:

> - This challenge is based on an old experiment.
> - Print generated resulting text with scrambled words.

Output:

> - This chllenage is based on an old exripmeent.
> - Print gertaneed reitlusng text with scbrmaled words.

## An example text for scrambled-words experiment. Version 2

### Challenge

The extended version of this challenge adds only one new assumption to base / above algorithm:

1. For each word in input text.

   - **If word is 4 characters long or less -- keep it unchanged**.
   - **If word is 5 characters long -- keep first and last character unchanged and scramble remaining three**.
   - If word is 6 characters long or longer -- keep first two and last two characters unchanged and scramble remaining ones.
2. Print generated resulting text with scrambled words.

And again:

1. Words with <del>5 characters</del> *4 characters* and less should be kept untouched.
2. Your code must support all UTF-8 characters, not just English / non-Latin alphabet.

### Example Input and Output

Input:

> - This challenge is based on an old experiment.
> - Print generated resulting text with scrambled words.

Output:

> - This chllenage is baesd on an old exripmeent.
> - Pirnt gertaneed reitlusng text with scbrmaled wrods.

Comment: See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9261/194 and the "Related questions" in its sidebar. This isn't identical, but I don't think it adds anything interesting.

Comment: I agree with @PeterTaylor; I don't think the differing lengths of what and when to scramble make this sufficiently different from the challenge he linked. Personally, I would dupe hammer this. Don't let that discourage you though; this was a well-written challenge for a newcomer and it's great to see a newcomer making use of the Sandbox. Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: I totally agree with both of you that moving this challenge out of Sandbox would produce us a perfect dupe! :> So, obviously, I am not going to do this. I have only one supporting question here. Do we have any tools / ways here at Code Golf to encourage particular language? Among all answers to question you pointed out there are no trace of solution in Javascript or any other way I could run this in a browser. Do I have any option to encourage such solution, if I need it (i.e. some bounty etc.)?

Comment: @trejder Yes, you can put a bounty on the [list of bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline). That means you offer a multiple of 50 (up to 500) of your own reputation.

Comment: @wastl Thanks for the suggestion, but I decided to go with a "regular" bounty instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Maximal number of programming languages in 1KiB

In this code-challenge your task is to write a program/function with a maximum of 1024 bytes, the goal is to interpret/compile as many programming languages as possible.

### Rules

You're free to use any combination of inputs and outputs as you wish.

#### Input

Inputs will be the name<sup>1</sup> of the programming language and the source code.

The inputs can be

- read from a file (you may hardcode a filename if it helps)
- read from *stdin*
- taken as command-line arguments
- taken as function arguments
- a combination of the above

<sup>1: you may choose to encode them, as long as the encoding is bijective - for example numbering the languages *1* through *n*.</sup>

#### Output

The output can be

- the resulting side-effects of interpreting the program in the specified language
- valid machine code that produces the above

#### What is a programming language?

For the purpose of this challenge a programming language needs to be

- Turing-complete
- publicly listed, as in having one of the following:

  - an entry on [Esolangs](https://esolangs.org/)
  - an entry on [Rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/)
  - an entry on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/)
  - an interpreter/compiler hosted on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
  - an interpreter/compiler hosted on [Github](https://github.com/)
  - an interpreter/compiler hosted on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/)
- released before 13. July 2018
- able to do I/O

#### What does my interpreter/compiler need to implement?

For each of the chosen programming languages, your program does not need to implement the full language. It suffices to implement a working subset of it as long as it stays Turing-complete.

### Scoring

The answer that implements the greatest number of different programming languages wins.

---

### Sandbox

**Tags:** [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter), [compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler)

- Should I leave the source size restriction and use a different scoring, eg. \$\frac{\#bytes}{\#langs ^ n}\$ for some \$n \ge 1\$?
- Should I disallow using polyglotting (maybe `eval` could be used several times that way which would be boring)?
- How should I properly define *different programming languages* (should I count different versions as 1 each)?
- Additional places for entries, descriptions of programming languages?
- Missing tags or other suggestions?

Comment: Given that Perl can do BF in [120 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/933/42963), I would think a bunch of BF derivatives like Ook could be tacked on for very little overhead, which would seem to break your scoring system. I'm not sure how to rule that out, though.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork: It kind of depends on what derivatives, I guess. You're right, I need to figure out a good way to rule out counting derivatives which just extend BF, otherwise it would be boring.. An idea would be: For each language you must give a program achieving some trivial task *X* and it isn't allowed to work in any other language.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: You're free to determine language by looking at the source, however you're given the name as input: *"Inputs will be the name of the programming language and the source code."* Just looked in meta and found [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442/48198), so I will remove the notice that you can ignore that input (I didn't know that before and didn't want to prevent people from determining the language themselves).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! Maybe it would be better to put that at the start of the input section? Something like: "Your interpreter will be given the source and language names as inputs inn one of the following ways: ..." perhaps?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for the feedback! I put it to the beginning of that section and removed the notice about encoding further information (it's a standard loophole anyways and doesn't make things clearer).

Answer (score 0):

## Irrational Array indexing Starts at 3.

I came across the following brilliant comment, which suggests that subsequent sets of digit from pi should be used to Index an array, from a user named on the r/programmer humor subreddit [context for the curious](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8ztjmn/arrays_start_at_05f/e2lo6l8/?context=3).

```
To fix the duplicate problem, instead take an extra digit whenever you are about
to duplicate a key: arr[3], arr[1], arr[4], arr[15], 
arr[9], arr[2], arr[6], arr[5], arr[35] and so on.

Exercise for the reader: write a program that outputs the nth index of this array, and describe for yourself the limitations of the program (what is the maximum value of n? what is the minimum?)
```

Your task (should you choose to accept it), is to implement a function (or rather pair of functions/ (pair of full programs/ one of each)) that converts to and from this cutting-edge choice.

You may either write a single function that receives two inputs one being an integer input, and two being which way to go, or you can write a pair of functions and your score will be the sum of their sizes.

Put another way, implement both f(x) and \$ f^{-1}(x) \$ according to this table. You may also instead implement f(x-1), and \$ f^{-1}(x) \$ + 1 (1 indexed arrays), but you will get some stern looks.

```
x f(x)
------
0 3
1 1
2 4
3 15
4 9
5 2
6 6
7 5
8 35
19 950
21 841
41 6280
```

This problem is essentially identical to [OEIS A064809](https://oeis.org/A064809), although the table there is one indexed.

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins. As always, you may use any programming language, but standard loopholes are prohibitted. What is allowed though, is that at no penalty you may optionally take in a second or third input with the first 10,000 digits of pi. Your code must work with 0<=x<=1000. Even if you choose to receive pi as input, I'll personally encourage you to write one that doesn't require pi as input, It'll obviously be unscored, but you'll earn some imaginary internet points.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Note that we have mathjax now so you could write \$ f^{-1}(x) \$ etc. You may also want to include the first 3-digit number in the examples. I also expect that every answer will choose to take the optional input, except for those that already have access to the digits of pi.

Comment: I suspect it too. I figured having to dynamically compute all of the digits of pi was a bit beyond the scope of challenge, but I really wanted to see answers that don't.

Comment: I think they might be different enough to be posted as two different challenges, but its a bit borderline so I'd definitely either ask chat or meta if you wanted to do that. Otherwise, there's not a particularly good reason not to require calculating digits of pi in this way, I think? So if that's the question you'd rather ask then go ahead. The only significant difference will probably be receiving fewer answers, and the only real drawback could be that people say its a dupe of finding pi to an arbitrary number of digits, perhaps.

Comment: This is [OEIS entry A064809](https://oeis.org/A064809). I actually had an idea for a similar challenge recently of splitting a given string into substrings in such a way as to avoid duplicate substrings.

Comment: "but standard loopholes are permitted" <- prohibited perhaps? "If you choose to not take in this input, your code must work with 0<=x<=1000" <- does this mean there's a different limit for those who do take that input? (It looks like with 10000 digits you'd be able to handle upto x = 2675.)

Comment: Definitely post 2 different challenges.

Comment: should I link them?

Comment: @sundar I'll make that limit apply to both. I'll still give you 10k digits of pi though, out of "kindness".

Answer (score 0):

## Encoding nested tuples

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [set-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory), [binary-tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-tree)

**Related:** [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119994/decode-the-void)

---

Working on my recent esolang [μ6](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mu6) I found myself a neat puzzle: Given the set of all natual numbers and the set of all nested tuples over the natural numbers, find a bijection between those two sets.

A nested tuple \$t \in T\$ is recursively defined, it is one of the two:

- an natural (\$\ n \in \mathbb{N}_0\ \$) number itself: \$\;t = n\$
- a tuple of two nested tuples (\$\ t_l,t_r \in T\ \$): \$\;t = (t_l,t_r)\$

If it helps you can think of a nested tuple as a binary tree that has only values in its leaves.

### Challenge

Your task is to define two programs/functions, let's call them \$\ E\ \$ (encode) and \$\ D\ \$ (decode) which are each others inverses:

Given any natural number \$n \in \mathbb{N}_0\$ the output \$E(n)\$ is a unique element of \$\ T\$ and \$\ D(E(n)) = n\$.

Given any nested tuple \$\ t \in T\$ the output \$\ D(t)\$ is a unique element of \$\ \mathbb{N}_0\$ and \$\ E(D(t)) = t\$.

### Rules

Inputs to the two programs/functions can be

- an integer or a string representation thereof for \$\ E\$
- a nested tuple/list, custom data-type<sup>1</sup> for \$\ D\$

Outputs can either be of the same type as the input of the inverse function/program or printed to *stdout*.

### Example

Since you're free to implement any bijection, it's difficult to give meaningful test cases. These are just a few examples using [this](https://github.com/bforte/mu6/blob/b881c56a85d439c1e9f17ee791448dc89e220c73/src/Eval.hs#L81) encoding-function and [this](https://github.com/bforte/mu6/blob/b881c56a85d439c1e9f17ee791448dc89e220c73/src/Eval.hs#L72) decoding-function:

```
0 <-> 0
1 <-> (0,0)
3 <-> ((0,0),0)
20415 <-> ((1,0),(1,2))
55340232221111877631 <-> ((0,(1,0)),(2,1))
1000000000000000000000000 <-> 500000000000000000000000
```

---

<sup>1: For example if your language doesn't support nested tuples/lists, you don't need to count its definition towards your byte count. As an example a Haskell submission could assume `data T = El Integer | Nest T T`.</sup>

## Sandbox

- Anything unclear?
- Is this maybe too much to ask in a code-golf?
- I could "simplify" it by asking for two \$\ E_k \$ and \$\ D_k \$ which would for all inputs \$ k \$ map \$\ \mathbb{N_0} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{N_0}^k\ \$..

Comment: We already have a few similar questions: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78606/194 ; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48705/194 ; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119994/194 ; etc. I don't think this is an exact duplicate of any of them, but it's sufficiently simple to build from a pairing function (let `(0,x)` denote leaf `x` and `(y,z)` denote a tuple, and ensure that `0` decodes to `(0,0)`) that I think it's a borderline dupe of at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

## Most Turing-incomplete Instruction Set

**Tags:** [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

---

This challenge expects you to define an instruction set \$I = \{ \texttt{instr}_1 \dots \texttt{instr}_n \}\$ which is provably [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). The catch is that any subset \$I'\$ that is proper (ie. \$I' \neq I\$) must not be Turing complete.

### Challenge

Your task is to define some environment (eg. a stack, an unbounded tape, tuples, integers, funcions etc.) over which you have complete freedom to choose, let us call this environment \$E\$.

To initialize \$E\$ you will define a way of transforming the source code \$s\$ and inputs \$in_0,\dots,in_r\$ to some \$E_{initial}\$. The same holds for the output of your programming language, you can define the output as any mapping of the end state \$E_{end}\$ to your output set.

The main task is to find an as large as possible number of instructions which define a Turing complete programming language, but removing any instruction from that set must result in a programming language that is not Turing complete.

An instruction \$\texttt{instr}_i\$ takes some non-negative number \$m\$ of arguments and modifies the environment, ie.

$$
\texttt{instr}_i : A_0 \times \cdots \times A_m \times E \to E
$$

where \$A_0,\dots,A_m\$ are the sets of valid arguments, you're free to define these as you wish (eg. natural numbers, integers, Booleans, labels etc.).

### Submission

Your submission will contain

- the language specification
- informal proof of validity
- an implementation of the language.

### Rules

- this is a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) and your score will be the number of instructions, the goal is to maximize this number (ties will be broken by favouring the earliest submission)
- your programming language only needs to support input by using some special initial environment \$E_{initial}\$
- the same holds for the output(s), these only need to be encoded in the final \$E_{end}\$
- the definitions of \$E\$ and the way of transforming input/output do not need to be formal (eg. it suffices to just say something along the lines of: *"My language works with a stack of integers, initially it will contain all the inputs beginning with the first one at the bottom of the stack. Output will be the top of the stack or zero if it's empty."*)
- you will need to provide an informal proof of why your submission is valid, consisting of

  - an informal proof of Turing completeness of the instruction set \$I\$
  - an informal proof of why any proper subset of \$I\$ is not Turing complete
- these proofs may rely on reductions to known Turing complete languages (eg. Turing machines, BitBitJump, brainfuck etc.)

## Sandbox

As pointed out by [Nathaniel](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21034/nathaniel?tab=profile), it is currently possible to get an arbitrary large score.. If anyone has a nice fix that will prevent that (and similar exploits), please leave a comment.

Comment: I like the idea, but the instruction set can easily be made arbitrarily large. E.g. environment starts in state 0. Instruction A1 changes the state to state 1 if it's in state 0, otherwise it's an error. Instruction A2 changes the state to state 2 if it's in state 1, otherwise it's an error. [...] Instruction A1000000 changes the state to state 1000000 if it's in state 999999, otherwise it's an error. Instructions S, K perform as per SK calculus, but only if the environment is in state 1000000. This scores 1000002.

Comment: @Nathaniel: I didn't think of that :( Finding a nice definition/rule to prevent these kinds of exploits will be quite difficult. I'll see what can be done.

Comment: For N*'s attack, a function can take binary input and decide one state per input

Comment: @l4m2: I thought about that too, it's better than what I have now. But it would still allow an "attack" where you abuse the stack/tape/.., for example: Take a setup with a stack, A1 pushes 1, A2 pushes 2 if ToS=1 else pushes 0, .. A<really-large-number> acts as a Turing-complete instruction when ToS = *<really-large-number>-1* and else it acts as clear stack.

Comment: Oh and there might be some confusion about state and environment which are not distinguished in that definition. Only allowing moving to one state/environment would prevent a regular `add` instruction, since the resulting state would be different for a lot of operands.

Comment: @OMᗺ It's still covered

Comment: @l4m2: But that would mean that there needs to bean infinite amount of states, each configuration of state and tape/stack/.. would be state. Leaving us with the problem that there can't be an instruction `put X` where `X` is placed on the tape/stack because it would be different for different `X`s. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Define the structure X as a non-empty array of (smaller) X objects and "1". Split an X object into the smallest amount of continuous parts Y, length of each of Y don't exceed n, so that each X is either part of a Y, or exactly some Ys. It's fine if output only express which part has how many 1's.

Samples:

```
[1,[1,1,1]],3 => 1;111
[1,[1,1,1]],2 => 1;11;1 or 1;1;11
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],1 => 1;1;1;1;1;1
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],2 => 11;1;11;1 or etc.
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],3 => 111;111
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],4 => 111;111
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],5 => 111;111
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],6 => 111111
```

Comment: What is a "non-self-contain array"?

Comment: @user202729 Some languages allow array like `A=[A]`, which is here not allowed

Comment: I think you should work on the explanation, it's not very clear without looking at the testcases. Also what about languages that don't allow lists/arrays with different types? Would it be ok to define an appropriate type? Or should input be taken as string?

Answer (score 0):

***Drat! This was actually run three years ago! See [Implement INTERCAL's Binary Operators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54412/implement-intercals-binary-operators)***

## Mingle and Select

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

The programming language INTERCAL has two operators, "mingle" or "interleave" (represented by `$`), and "select" (represented by `~`).

**Mingle** takes two 16-bit values and produces a 32-bit value by taking single bits alternately from its left and right operands, and concatenating them together - for example, `65535 $ 0` will yield `-1431655766` as follows: 65535 is 0xFFFF, or 0b1111111111111111; 0 is 0b0000000000000000. Taking the bits alternately gives 0b10101010101010101010101010101010, or 0xAAAAAAAA, which evaluates to the signed integer -1431655766.

A simplified implementation of **Select** takes two 32-bit operands, and produces a 32-bit value by comparing the bits in the two operands, and wherever the right operand has a 1 bit, take the corresponding bit from the left operand. The resulting bits are compressed to the right, and zero-filled on the left - for example, an 8-bit version of select, given `79 ~ 42`, would return `3`, as follows: 79 is 0b01001111, and 42 is 0b00101010. Numbering the bits from the left starting with 1, we need to take the third, fifth, and seventh bits of 79, which are 0, 1, and 1, respectively. We then compress them to the right - 011 - and zero-fill, yielding 0b00000011, or 3.

#### The challenge

Without using INTERCAL, and without using in any other language any <s>operator</s> builtin that amounts to either mingle or select, implement both operators. You may implement them <s>for 16- or 32-bit integers, and</s> as either operators or functions, but input and output must be UNsigned decimal integers. (I'm not going to require input or output in INTERCAL-style insanity!)

Further constraint: The minimum bit width of the operands must be 16 bits for `mingle` (no constraint for `select`), and if they are unequal in width, the shorter is zero-filled on the left to match the width of the longer (zero fill applies to both `mingle` and `select`).

*test cases to be written and inserted here*

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in each language 'wins'. (Naturally, the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.)

Comment: "*You may implement them for 16- or 32-bit integers, and as either operators or functions, but input and output must be signed decimal integers.*" This puts languages such as CJam which only have unbounded integer types at a disadvantage. Is that intended?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - The intent here is not to exclude or disadvantage any particular language (other than INTERCAL), but to 'force' zero-fill on `select`, and return negative values for some cases of `mingle`. Would it be better to say that values returned must be some power of 2 times 16-bits wide?

Comment: I'm not sure why an integer width is necessary for `select`: just say that it's zero-filled and make sure that the corner case of `a ~ -1` (the only way that there's nothing to fill) is covered by test cases for `a` positive, zero, and negative.

Comment: For `mingle`, it seems to me that if the operands are really 16-bit values then the example should be `-1 $ 0`, and if you require the output to be negative iff the first operand is negative then it easily generalises to unbounded integer types. However, the result of `-1 $ 0` in an unbounded type is unbounded, so there is a genuine problem there. I suggest mentioning that briefly as a rationale for why languages without bounded integer types must nevertheless implement a bounded `mingle`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - but zero-filled to what width? One could argue that if an arbwidth is allowed, then no zeros need to be added, and `79 ~ 10` could validly be argued to be -1.

Comment: To infinite width. The most significant bit is effectively a sign bit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Good catch on 65535 vs -1. I think that this and the arbwidth problem can be addressed by simply changing the 'signed' constraint to 'unsigned'.

Comment: But how do I tell the (`select`ed) MSB from presumed zero-filling? Is `79~10` equal to 3, or to -1?

Comment: UPDATE: Constraints changed.

Comment: "*But how do I tell the (`select`ed) MSB from presumed zero-filling?*" The answer would have been that you can only get a negative result if both operands are negative, but now that you've changed to unsigned this is no longer an issue.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - It's been rendered academic; the challenge has already been run - see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54412/implement-intercals-binary-operators

Answer (score 0):

## Game of Circles [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

This is a hidden-identity game with Detectives and Robbers.  You will write either a Detective bot or a Robber bot.  All Robbers know the identity of all other Robbers.  Each turn, a bot must either:

1. Draw a private circle:

   - The actual circle drawn is public information
   - Detectives receive the number of Robbers in the circle privately
2. Draw a public circle

   - The player that draws the circle declares the number of robbers in the circle (may or may not be true)

Finally, the player with the most circles (public or private) around them dies.  In the case of a tie, no player dies.

The game ends when a single side has been eliminated or when no players have died for 3 turns.

Each game consists of 17 Detective and 3 Robbers.  (META:  These numbers I'm not sure about).

The bots that will participate in each game will be chosen using two genetic algorithms.
There will be 100 simultaneous games, and the first genetic algorithm will choose the 1700 players for the Detectives, while the second genetic algorithm will choose the 300 Robbers.  The fitness function for each bot will be how long they survived in the game (by percentage).

After 1000 rounds, players are ranked by their population (two scoreboards, one for Detectives, one for Robbers)

Comment: Sounds kinda like the Werewolf/Mafia game. Makes me wonder how well [The Resistance](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41114/resistance) boardgame will translate to a KotH.

Comment: I don't understand the bit about genetic algorithms though - will the bots that we submit just be the base population for the GA then? Or will there be no mutation or crossover in the GA (in which case it's pretty much not a GA)? That bit needs some more elaboration and possibly some tweaking.

Comment: Yep, this is similar to Werewolf/Mafia.  I considered starting out with that, but I thought it might cause some confusion as there is no "nighttime", and robbers have no extra powers outside of knowing all of the other robbers.

Comment: The bots will be the base population.  Breeding will be asexual (single parent), and mutations means randomly picking a bot.  You are right, this isn't a string GA, but it's the best term I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

## 4B/5B Encoding

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode), [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

To transmit data in binary there's a technique called [NRZI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero#NRZI) where a transition from *+V* to *-V* or vice-versa encodes a *1* and the absence of such a transition a *0*.

In case there are a lot of *1* s this is a good method because there will be a lot of transmissions and the risk of getting out of sync is smaller, however it's still tricky for long runs of *0*. One solution is [4B/5B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4B5B#Encoding_table) encoding which takes 4bits and encodes it in 5bits in a way such that there are at most 3 consecutive bits. The encoding is as follows:

```
0000 -> 11110
0001 -> 01001
0010 -> 10100
0011 -> 10101
0100 -> 01010
0101 -> 01011
0110 -> 01110
0111 -> 01111
1000 -> 10010
1001 -> 10011
1010 -> 10110
1011 -> 10111
1100 -> 11010
1101 -> 11011
1110 -> 11100
1111 -> 11101
```

### Challenge

Given an bytestring, you will need to encode it with the aforementioned encoding.

### Rules

- Input will be a bytestring

  - to avoid padding-issues, it will always have a length that is a multiple of 4 bytes
- Output will be of the same a bytestring
- You may not assume that input (nor output) is printable

### Examples

**Note:** You need to handle both printable and unprintable examples!

#### ASCII examples

```
ORLY -> WWEis
OBMO -> WUEm]
SSePCcGG -> ]WW-~U]U=O
aHAHaHAHaHAHaHAHaHaO -> rU%%RrU%%RrU%%RrU%%RrU'%]
S#KPOCFWcSaOCR!@sz!\q9OKqY!L -> ]iU]~WUU9ouWW%]UWJ%^}_j%zzk5uWzW:%Z
```

#### Unprintables in hexadecimal

```
c0 ff ee 00 -> d7 bb de 73 de
66 6f 6f 00 -> 73 9d d7 77 de
50 50 43 47 -> 5f 97 e5 55 4f
48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 00 00 00 -> 54 9c b7 69 da 77 69 aa 79 6f 77 5f 47 69 ca a2 7d ef 7b de
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lucas and Fibonacci are in pair](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171122/lucas-and-fibonacci-are-in-pair)

Answer (score 0):

## Delimiter-Chaos

Write a program of at most 150 bytes length that produces different outputs (to stdout) if you insert token-delimiters into the source code.

### Score

The program with the highest number of different outputs wins.

### Rules

For this challenge, we assume that the source code is tokenized prior to compilation/ interpretation.
A **delimiter** is any character which, when inserted at a given position, changes the way the source code is tokenized, but is not part of a token on its own.

### Example

(python)

```
a = "0"
b = "0"
ainb="12"
print(ainb)
```

This prints 12.
If you insert two spaces, you get:

```
a = "0"
b = "0"
ainb="12"
print(a in b)
```

which prints "True"

This gives a total score of 2 for 2 (known) different outputs

### Rule clarifications

- Only program versions that exit with zero error code count towards the score.
- All versions have to be listed explicitly in the answer.
- Put the score into the title of the answer.
- If your code produces different outputs in different programming languages, they count.

Answer (score 0):

## Write in Ge'ez!

[Ge'ez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez) is a now-dead language used for liturgy in the Ethiopian Orthodox Church. It's traditionally written in a very distinctive script with many loops and curves. But for ease of reading, it's often transliterated into Latin letters.

Your task here is to take some writing in Latin characters and convert it to the Ge'ez script. For example, the input `gəʿəz` (the name of the language) should give the output `ግዕዝ`.

#### Details

Every letter in the Ge'ez script represents both a consonant and the following vowel. There are eight vowels

```
ä u i a e ə o wa
```

and twenty-six consonants

```
h l ḥ m ś r s ḳ b t ḫ n ʾ k w ʿ z y d g ṭ p̣ ṣ ḍ f p
```

which give 208 combinations. (In reality, some of these combinations like "wwa" don't actually happen, and there are some extra letters like "mya" not covered by this system, but ignore all that for the purposes of the challenge.)

The combinations are encoded in a convenient way in Unicode. The consonant defines the starting position, and the vowel defines the offset.

```
C    start (hex)
----------------
h    1200
l    1208
ḥ    1210
m    1218
ś    1220
r    1228
s    1230
q    1240
b    1260
t    1270
x    1280
n    1290
ʾ    12A0
k    12A8
w    12C8
ʿ    12D0
z    12D8
y    12E8
d    12F0
g    1308
ṭ    1320
p̣    1330
ṣ    1338
ḍ    1340
f    1348
p    1350

V    offset
-----------
ä    +0
u    +1
i    +2
a    +3
e    +4
ə    +5
o    +6
wa   +7
```

(Again, reality is a bit more complicated, but ignore that for the challenge.)

Your task is to take a string written in Latin letters, and output the corresponding Ge'ez syllables. If a consonant is followed by a vowel, add the consonant's start point to the vowel's offset, and print the corresponding Unicode character. If a consonant is not followed by a vowel, use the start point with no offset (as if the vowel were `ä`).

Input is a Unicode string, or a list of Unicode codepoints as integers. Output is a Unicode string, or a list of Unicode codepoints as integers. A "Unicode string" here can be in any official encoding (UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32…). NFC and NFD are both acceptable.

This is code golf; shortest code (in bytes) in each language wins. Standard loopholes forbidden.

Test cases:

```
gəʿəz    ግዕዝ
[TODO more to come here]
```

Comment: One option would be replacing the Unicode characters in the input with ASCII digraphs. Would this make the challenge better?

Answer (score 0):

### Compute strings with a fixed distance

Consider a binary string of total length N. For example 000111000111 with \$N=12\$. We can store this string more efficiently by just recording the indices where bits are first flipped. In this case \$(3, 6, 9)\$ is sufficient information to reproduce the string. Here are some more examples using this representation:

```
10101010 is represented inefficiently by (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
1111100000 is represented by (0, 5)
0000011111 is represented by (5)
```

Let us call this representation of a string its  `compressed representation` (even though sometimes the compression is worse than doing nothing).

Now recall the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings. This is the minimum number of single character insertions, deletions and substitutions needed to transform one string into the other.

## Task

Given a compressed representation of a string \$S\$ of uncompressed length \$N\$ and two positive integers \$k\$ and \$d\$, the task is to output the compressed representation of \$k\$ distinct strings of uncompressed length \$N\$, each with Levenshtein distance exactly \$d\$ from \$S\$. If there are not that many distinct strings possible, simply output as many as possible.

Your code must run with \$N = 1000000\$ and \$k, d < 20\$ in less than a minute on a normal desktop PC.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here.  Everything above "Task" is clear, but I don't understand what's going on below.  If S = "0000", k = 1, and d = 1, then I simply print out one of "1000", "0100", "0010","0001" (in compressed format)?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes. It’s less trivial with other starting strings and larger d.

Comment: Right.  There seems to be two parts to this challenge then:  Iterating through Levenshtien mutations, and converting to/from the compressed representation.  Unless I'm missing how they are related, I'd argue that you remove one of the parts.

Comment: It appears that iterating Levenshtien mutations would [be a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37979/find-all-strings-at-distance-k)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thanks for the possible dupe link.  For your first comment, the idea was to do it without first uncompressing. I will try to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Bijective base banana to decimal

I'm trying to decide between 2 versions of this challenge:

---

## Prefixes version

Let bijective base banana be [bijective base 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) with each digit represented by a different prefix of the word "banana" as follows:

```
1: "b"
2: "ba"
3: "ban"
4: "bana"
5: "banan"
6: "banana"
```

The input will be a string made up of a concatenation of zero or more of only these strings. This represents a number in bijective base 6 (with most significant digit first).

The output will be the same number in (non-bijective) decimal.

For example: (input : output)

```
"" : 0
"b" : 1
"bb" : 7
"bbanana" : 12
"bananab" : 37
"bananabanana" : 42
```

A worked example:

```
bananabanbana
banana ban bana
6      3   4
6*36 + 3*6 + 4*1
216  + 18  + 4
238
```

This is code golf, so the winner for each language is the code with the fewest bytes.

---

## Suffixes version

Let bijective base banana be [bijective base 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) with each digit represented by a different suffix of the word "banana" as follows:

```
1: "a"
2: "na"
3: "ana"
4: "nana"
5: "anana"
6: "banana"
```

The input will be a string made up of a concatenation of zero or more of only these strings. This represents a number in bijective base 6 (with most significant digit first).

The output will be the same number in (non-bijective) decimal.

For example: (input : output)

```
"" : 0
"a" : 1
"aa" : 7
"abanana" : 12
"bananaa" : 37
"bananabanana" : 42
```

A worked example:

```
bananaananana
banana ana nana
6      3   4
6*36 + 3*6 + 4*1
216  + 18  + 4
238
```

This is code golf, so the winner for each language is the code with the fewest bytes.

---

## Sandbox questions

- Is this a duplicate or near enough a duplicate to be worth changing?
- Are there any flaws that would make the challenge uninteresting?
- I'm considering changing from prefixes to suffixes following [this comment from H.PWiz](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16860?noredirect=1#comment59419_16860)
- I currently prefer the suffixes version, but the worked example shows that the interpretation is no longer unique. It would either need to be specified that the match must be greedy (or non-greedy) or a different word would need to be chosen. I lean towards choosing a word which still gives enough ambiguity to force looking ahead, while still keeping the overall conclusion unique. I can't see a way of doing this without making the last character unique though, which reduces to a reversed version of the prefixes version (you can still ignore all other letters).

Comment: This is interesting, but I can't help but feel like this is two problems glued into one.

Comment: It's definitely 2 problems glued onto 1. What I'm wondering is will that make for additional golfing opportunities in at least some languages? I suspect it will, and I'd expect myself to underestimate the possibilities since there are many more insightful people tackling challenges, in many languages.

Comment: Hmm, It seems like all that matters is where the `b`s are. I wonder if it would be a more or less interesting challenge with a different word

Comment: Good point. Suffixes instead of prefixes might give a bit more of a challenge. As long as the output is still guaranteed unique

Comment: @trichoplax I'm pretty sure you can't do suffixes, since its no longer unique.

Comment: @RushabhMehta yes it stops working for the word "banana" then (I added a note about this in my 4th sandbox point). It would still work for words that don't contain any of their own suffixes as non-suffix substrings. Like "aardvark". I'm not sure which way to go yet

Comment: @trichoplax Your last bullet was exactly my issue. Suffixes don't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the fixed point prime

[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)[recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion)

---

## Definition

Let `f(n)` be the sum of the sums of each possible factor permutation of `n`. Determine `(Y f)(n)` (a [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)) for all `n` from 2 to the input `i` (where `i` is an integer greater than 2).

## Example

A quick example of `f(n)` first:

```
f(8) = (2 + 2 + 2) + (2 + 4) + (4 + 2) + (8)
f(8) = 26
```

An example of `(Y f)(n)`:

```
(Y f)(8)
  f(8) = 26 (shown above)
  f(26) = (2 + 13) + (26) = 41
  f(41) = (41) = 41
(Y f)(8) = 41
```

Let `g(i)` define a function which implements the described problem.

```
g(2)
2

g(4)
2
3
41

g(8)
2
3
41
5
11
7
41
```

## Competition

This is a [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) challenge, which means that the solution with the lowest asymptotic time complexity (in [Θ(...)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)) wins!

In the case of a tie, the winner will be determined by [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) rules, so please submit an implementation of your code along with the algorithm. Tie-break will occur on a [Google Compute Engine n1-standard-8 instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).

Comment: In your example of `f(8)`, why do you include 1 in `(8+1)`? Should it not be just `(8)`? I could make `(2+2+2)` into `(2+2+2+1)`.

Comment: @RushabhMehta You're entirely correct! My bad, let me fix that.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that in your system, the only fixed points are prime numbers. Is that desired functionality?

Comment: @RushabhMehta See the title. :P

Comment: Finally, I would mention that permutations are distinct, just so that its obvious how you are counting all the different factors.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Is that a sufficient change?

Comment: That should be fine. Nice challenge!

Comment: 1. What's a *factor permutation*? 2. I doubt anyone can give even a moderately tight analysis of the runtime for an implementation of `g` without a very tight analysis of the output of `f`, so I don't think it makes sense to post this without first editing in tight bounds on the output of `f`.

Answer (score 0):

## Facto-RLE

### Task

Given a non-empty string containing non-numeric printable ASCII characters, compute its facto-run-length encoded version.

### Definition

Let \$S\$ be a non-empty string of length \$l\in\mathbb{N}^+\$ containing non-numeric printable ASCII characters. For each positive factor \$n|l\$ one can represent \$S\$ as a \$n\times(l/n)\$ matrix of characters. Let \$M^n\$ denote these matrices.
For a given \$n\$ and \$j\in\{1,\dots,l/n\}\$, let \$C^n_j\$ be the string representing the \$j\$-th column of \$M^n\$. Let \$E^n_j := \text{RLE}(C^n_j)\$ denote the array of this string's run-length encoded version.
Let \$R^n := \text{CNCT}(\text{ZIP}(E^n_1,\dots,E^n_{l/n}))\$ denote the string representation of all \$E^n_j\$ zipped together.
The facto-run-length encoding of \$S\$ is defined as the string array \$\text{FRLE}(S):=[R^n:n|l]\$.

For a family of \$k\in\mathbb{N}^+\$ arrays \$A^i\$ with respective lengths \$l^i, i\in\{1,\dots,k\}\$ and elements \$A^i_j,j\in\{1,\dots,l^i\}\$, let \$Z_j:=[A^i_j:i\in\{1,\dots,k\}\land j\leq l_i]\$ denote the array of elements with index \$j\$, if present. Furthermore, define \$\text{ZIP}(A^1,\dots,A^k) := Z_1\Vert\dots\Vert Z_{\max\{l_i\}}\$ as the concatenated array of all \$Z_j\$.
For an array of strings \$A\$ of length \$j\$, define \$\text{CNCT(A)}:=A_1\Vert \dots\Vert A_j\$ as the concatenation of all strings of \$A\$.

### Example

Let \$S:=\text{"Hello world!"}\$, therefore \$l=12\$ with positive factors \$\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}\$.
$$
M^2=\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{H}&\text{e}&\text{l}&\text{l}&\text{o}&\text{ }\\
   \text{w}&\text{o}&\text{r}&\text{l}&\text{d}&\text{!}
\end{pmatrix},
\\C^2_1=\text{"Hw"},
C^2_2=\text{"eo"},
C^2_3=\text{"lr"},
\\C^2_4=\text{"ll"},
C^2_5=\text{"od"},
C^2_6=\text{" !"},
\\E^2_1=[\text{"H"},\text{"w"}],
E^2_2=[\text{"e"},\text{"o"}],
E^2_3=[\text{"l"},\text{"r"}],
\\E^2_4=[\text{"l2"}],
E^2_5=[\text{"o"},\text{"d"}],
E^2_6=[\text{" "},\text{"!"}],
\\R^2=\text{"Hell2o word!"}
$$

$$
M^4=\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{H}&\text{e}&\text{l}\\
   \text{l}&\text{o}&\text{ }\\
   \text{w}&\text{o}&\text{r}\\
   \text{l}&\text{d}&\text{!}\\
\end{pmatrix},
\\C^4_1=\text{"Hlwl"},
C^4_2=\text{"eood"},
C^4_3=\text{"l r!"},
\\E^4_1=[\text{"H"}, \text{"l"}, \text{"w"}, \text{"l"}],
E^4_2=[\text{"e"}, \text{"o2"}, \text{"d"}],
E^4_1=[\text{"l"}, \text{" "}, \text{"r"}, \text{"!"}],\\
R^4=\text{STR}([\text{"H"},\text{"e"},\text{"l"},\text{"l"},\text{"o2"},\text{" "},\text{"w"},\text{"d"},\text{"r"},\text{"l"},\text{"!"}])=\text{"Hello2 wdrl!"}
$$

$$
M^{12}=\begin{pmatrix}
   \text{H}\\
   \text{e}\\
   \text{l}\\
   \text{l}\\
   \text{o}\\
   \text{ }\\
   \text{w}\\
   \text{o}\\
   \text{r}\\
   \text{l}\\
   \text{d}\\
   \text{!}\\
\end{pmatrix},
\\C^{12}_1=\text{"Hello world!"},
\\E^{12}_1=[\text{"H"},\text{"e"},\text{"l2"},\text{"o"},\text{" "},\text{"w"},\text{"o"},\text{"r"},\text{"l"},\text{"d"},\text{"!"}],
\\R^{12}=\text{"Hel2o world!"}
$$

Therefore the following follows.
$$
   \text{FRLE}(\text{"Hello world!"}) = [\dots, \text{"Hell2o word!"}, \dots, \text{"Hello2 wdrl!"}, \dots, \text{"Hel2o world!"}]
$$

### Tags [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: If you can't think of a way to put it into words, you could put it into code, and then someone here can translate that reference implementation into a description. Plus you can then include the reference implementation in the spec for people who read code better than prose

Comment: Okay,I can do that!

Comment: @Zacharý I have attempted to write a task definition. If this is not what you intended, you can simply roll back.

Comment: By the way, I think giving a factor as input would be a nicer challenge than adding a wrapper to encode for every factor.

Comment: @JonathanFrech, there isn't universal agreement on the meaning of `zip` applied to a non-square 2D array, so you need to define it unambiguously.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Attempted to do so. I intend to only zip one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I think this definition works!

Answer (score 0):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)
I have an idea for a KOTH challenge (that is marginally similar to the current [Reaper KOTH)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172102/lets-play-some-reaper), but none of the expertise required to make it work. The idea is based on the card game [Diamant](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15512/diamant) aka Incan Gold, and the rules of the game are:

- The game is played over 5 expeditions, each with the same structure.
- At the start of each expedition, a special deck of cards is shuffled, containing gem cards and hazard cards (and in some versions of the game, one artifact card is added to the deck every expedition).
- Every turn, a card is revealed from the deck.

  - If a hazard card is revealed and another copy of the same hazard has already been revealed in the expedition, the expedition immediately ends and all remaining players lose their accumulated gems. The revealed hazard card is removed from the deck for future expeditions.
  - If a gem card is revealed, the number of gems shown on the card is shared evenly between remaining players, with any remainder placed in a common pool.
- After the card is revealed, if the expedition has not ended, then players simultaneously decide whether they want to "Stay" or "Go Home".

  - All players who choose "Go Home" share the gems in the common pool between them (leaving any remainder), and then bank all of their gems. They are no longer in the expedition.
  - If a single player chooses "Go Home", they claim all of the gems in the common pool plus any artifacts that were revealed.
- If there are players remaining in the expedition, then a new turn begins.
- If there are no players remaining in the expedition, then the expedition ends.

  - If this was the last expedition, then players count up the gems they banked plus bonus gems for artifacts they claimed, and the player with the most gems wins.

My thought is that we could simplify the game for KOTH - one expedition, no artifacts - and run games which pit 4 bots against each other in some configuration, with each bot's overall rating being its average score per game.

The problem is that I have no experience in any meaningful programming languages. The other problem is that I don't know how to run a contest like that. The other other problem is that I don't know whether it's worth running.

Can anyone offer assistance or advice on any of those three problems?

Comment: For problem 1, there are 2 optinos, either ask somebody else to write the bot (if the challenge is interesting enough), or to learn a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

## Output the answer after yours [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

Related:
[Output the answer above yours](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34705/output-the-answer-above-yours)

This challenge is very similar to the above, but I hope it's different enough to warrant posting. The difference is that you need to post the answer that is posted after yours (the whole answer, not just the <code> block). Also, your output can be the answer text or the HTML code of the answer. When your post is still the newest post, your program should just output nothing.

### Rules

1. No URL Shorteners
2. No programs that need to be run at a specific URL.
3. No updating your answer with information gained after posting (i.e your answer id, text or answer id of post that comes after yours). **Exception:** It's OK to hardcode the page number of your answer (on 'oldest' sort).

I think mine is different enough from the linked question, because that has some different rules, and my version closes loopholes used on the other question. Also, no one utilizes the StackAPI on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Put `+`, `-`, `*` into `1 _ 2 _ 3 ... n` to make the expression equal `0`, for a given `3 <= n <= 30`, and output the valid equation (`0=1+2-3`). Exactly one operator between each number.

---

There exists some patterns, such as `((1-2)-(3-4))+((5-6)-(7-8))...` and `1+((2-3)-(4-5))+(6-7)`. Maybe we can find patterns that solve the whole problem?

There are no solutions without `*` for at least `n={5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22}`, so it looks like we need `*` for `n=4x+1` and `n=4x+2`.

There are no solutions without `+` for `n < 18`.

There are no solutions without `-` (obviously).

---

Brute-forced examples:

3. 0=1+2-3
4. 0=1-2-3+4
5. 0=1*2-3-4+5
6. 0=1+2*3+4-5-6
7. 0=1+2-3-4+5+6-7
8. 0=1*2*3+4-5-6-7+8
9. 0=1-2+3*4*5+6-7*8-9
10. 0=1-2*3+4*5-6*7+8+9+10
11. 0=1*2+3*4+5*6-7*8-9+10+11
12. 0=1-2+3*4-5*6-7-8*9+10*11-12
13. 0=1+2*3+4+5-6-7-8+9+10+11-12-13
14. 0=1*2+3*4+5*6+7+8*9+10-11*12+13-14
15. 0=1-2-3-4-5-6-7+8-9+10-11+12-13+14+15
16. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6+7+8-9*10*11-12+13+14+15*16
17. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6+7*8*9+10-11*12*13+14*15+16*17
18. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6-7*8-9-10-11*12-13-14*15-16*17-18
19. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6-7-8-9*10-11-12-13-14-15*16-17*18-19
20. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6-7-8-9*10-11-12-13*14-15-16-17-18*19-20
21. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6-7-8-9-10-11-12*13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20*21
22. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6-7-8-9-10-11*12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20*21-22
23. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7-8*9-10*11-12-13*14-15*16*17-18-19-20-21-22*23
24. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7-8*9*10-11-12-13-14*15*16-17-18-19*20-21*22-23-24
25. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7-8*9*10-11-12*13*14-15*16-17-18*19-20*21-22*23-24*25
26. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8-9*10*11-12*13*14-15*16*17-18*19*20-21*22*23-24*25*26
27. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8-9*10*11-12-13*14*15-16-17-18*19*20-21-22*23*24-25*26*27
28. 0=1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9-10-11*12*13*14*15-16-17-18-19-20-21*22-23*24-25*26-27*28

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/generate-a-valid-equation-using-user-specified-numbers) Also, do you want this to be code golf (shortest code) or a different type of challenge?

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154763/make-zero-from-first-n-numbers).

Comment: @user202729 yep. Unlike that one, this doesn't allow turning the 1 negative, which does seem to make the problem unsolvable without multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice task [One Ring to rule them all. One String to contain them all](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13088). But rule define a string as a linear buffer. A linear buffer is not a *Ring* :)

My suggestion is:

- create a new task with title "One Ring to rule them all. One Ring to bring them all"
- add link to old task in the body of the new task
- modify an Objective: Output a String which contains every positive integer strictly below 1000 and the String is a [Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: [It would be a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42728/194)

Comment: ok. thanks, Peter

Comment: I've been thinking about it - no, It is not a duplicate. Main different: 0, 00, 000, ... are different elements in a [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) and same element in a [Ring of numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13088). This moment make **golfed** algoritms different.

Comment: In a de Bruijn sequence containing all 3-digit sequences over `0-9`, `000` is an element but `0` and `00` are not. Moreover, if the ring contains `100`, `200`, etc. then it must contain `00` at least nine times. See my comment of Nov 5 '13 at 11:28 on /q/13088.

Answer (score 0):

**Make words** (need a better title)

Write a program or function that takes a string and an integer \$ n \$ as input and outputs all the \$n\$-letter words formed using only the letters in the string.

Notes:

The input string will have only small alphabets \$a-z\$.

All the letters in the input string will be unique.

Input integer will be positive.

*Winner*:
This is code-golf so shortest code wins.
(Fastest algorithm will also be good in this right?)

*Examples:*

```
input:"abcd",5
output: "aaaaa","aaaab","aaaac",.....,"ddddc","ddddd"
```

P.S. The output does not have to be sorted.

Any input and output format will do as long as its distinguishable.

Example:

```
input: abcd,5 (ok)
       abcd 5 (ok)
       abcd5 (not allowed)
output: ["aaaaa","aaaab",.... (ok)
        "aaaaa","aaaab",.... (ok)
        "aaaaa""aaaab""aaaac"..... (ok)
        aaaaa aaaab aaaac ..... (ok)
        aaaaaaaaabaaaac...... (not allowed)
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53272/58563), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53001/58563), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79304/58563).

Comment: For this kind of challenge, neither `fastest-algorithm` nor `fastest-code` should be used. For the first one: all answers are likely to have the same time complexity. For the 2nd one: ~99% of CPU time is going to be spent printing the results.

Comment: BTW: this is basically _count from \$0\$ to \$b^n\$ in custom base \$b\$_, which may have already been covered in some other challenge. I failed to find one, though.

Comment: It's `product` in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html (May help giving a title to the challenge, or searching for duplicates)

Comment: @Arnauld It's mostly a duplicate of [Cartesian product of a list with itself n times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times). The only difference is that builtins aren't allowed in that linked challenge, which is probably better since this is [3 bytes in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0/Pw4v//E5OSU7hMAQ) due to an optional parameters requiring an explicit input and even just [1 byte in Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzun///9XSkxKTlH6bwoA) (not sure how to pretty-print it as a list in the footer..).

Answer (score 0):

## Golf A Programming Language

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Code golf languages are languages built to complete programming challenges in few lines of code. Instead of creating a code golf language, you will be creating an interpreter for a programming language in as few bytes as possible.

### Scoring

As you are not creating a code golf language, instead your score will be based on the number of bytes in the interpreter.

### I/O

You may provide a program as input to your interpreter as input using any [standard input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) method

Output provided by a program in your language may be passed on through your interpereter using any [standard output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) method

### Tasks

You must write a program to solve each task in the language you created:

- [Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) - Output the string "Hello World"
- [Fizz Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz) - List numbers from 1 to 100 replacing multiples of 3 with `Fizz`, 5 with `Buzz`, and 15 with `FizzBuzz`
- [Prime Check](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime) - Check if a given number is prime

### Loopholes

Your programming language must be implemented yourself. Using builtin functions such as Javascript's `eval` or CHIQRSX9+'s `I` on input makes this not very interesting.

Comment: This is too broad, as defining "interpreter" is pretty impossible.  The only way this is viable is if you specify the language to be interpreted.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Anything can be built for the interpreter. It could have 3 instructions, one for each challenge, but that could mean the interpreter increases length because it has the tasks built in. It might need more tasks, 3 tasks might mean building an actual language takes more code than just hardcoding 3 functions

Comment: Writing a general purpose language *will* take more characters than providing built-ins for those.  In essence, you're looking for a program that returns a program that takes 1 of 3 characters and evals it.  You are correct that `eval` makes this not interesting, but it's also the best way.  Unless you make the language significantly harder (and specify the input required to do each of the tasks), I don't see this being interesting.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111278/turing-complete-language-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

## Eeny Meeny Miny Moe

Inspired (somewhat) by [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/eeny-meeny-miny-moe/69808):

Where should I stand to be captain of my team?

## Introduction

The childhood song *Eeny, meeny, miny, moe* was often used to select who was a captain when playing some game.  Everyone on one team would stand in a line and someone would point at the first person in the line.  Although there are several variations, where I grew up, they would sing:

> Eeny, meeny, miny, moe,
>   Catch a tiger by the toe.
>   If he hollers, let him go,
>   Eeny, meeny, miny, moe.

adding to the traditional:

> My mother told me to pick the very best one and you are not it.

As we sung each word, we pointed at the next person in line, then (if the rhyme wasn't over yet) we would continue the rhyme and start over at the beginning of the line.  The person being pointed to when the final "it" was sung would be removed from the line, eliminating them from being captain.  Then the rhyme would start over at the beginning of the line to remove the next person.  This continued until only one person was left, and that person would be captain.

It didn't take long for me to recognize that if there were two people left (or if we started with just two people), it seemed like the second person would always win.  Studying this for a bit I realized that since there are 35 beats this would always happen.  I further figured out if there are 3 people, the third would win.  So I wondered: could I chart it out for any number?  Can I create a formula for it?

## Challenge:

Write a program, function or (etc. as standard) where given input of an integer number of starting children greater than one, output what starting child number will be the winner, and where I need to stand so that I can be captain!

## Examples:

```
Input        Output
  2             2
  3             3
4,5,6or7        4
 8 or 9         5
  10            6
11,12or13       7
  14            8
  15            9
  16           10
17,18,19or20   11
```

Winner for each language is that with the least number of bytes.  And of course, standard loopholes and all that legal jazz are not allowed as is typically expected in these challenges.

Comment: aka, the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), possibly [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/josephus-problem-counting-out)

Comment: @ngn Wow!  I learn something new every day!  Is this a duplicate, then?

Comment: I'm not sure, yours is a special case for k=35

Comment: by the way, you may find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE) enlightening :)

Comment: Different from listed duplicate in several ways.  Mine restarts at the beginning after each elimination (which really makes it questionable whether it is Josephus or not).  Mine requires only one input.  Mine is a firm case for k and mine has a cool backstory :)

Answer (score 0):

### Permutations to the nines

This question is based on an unresolved inquiry which began at [Permutations without recursive function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013675/permutations-without-recursive-function-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) and was followed up at [How to improve efficiency of algorithm which generates next lexicographic permutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290467/how-to-improve-efficiency-of-algorithm-which-generates-next-lexicographic-permut) (TL;DR), after finding help removing duplicate numbers at [Most efficient method to check for range of numbers within number without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487374/most-efficient-method-to-check-for-range-of-numbers-within-number-without-duplic), where after performing arithmetic by hand found that for an array having length less than or equal to `9`, if we ignore the value held at each index of the initial array and instead convert the indexes to a whole number, the next lexicographic permutation can be determined by adding `9` to the current index as number until a whole number, e.g., `[1,2,3] // 123 1-based index or 23 0-based index` is reached that satisfies two the conditions

- Contains only the numbers of the indexes of the original array
- Does not contain any duplicate numbers

e.g., `123+9=132 // "abc" -> "acb" 132-9=123 // "acb" -> "abc"`; the graph for `"abcd"` is

> `[9,81,18,81,9,702,9,171,27,72,18,693,18,72,27,171,9,702,9,81,18,81,9]`

which does not appear to be linear.

As the linked answers disclose, adding `9` to a whole number is not the most efficient method of determining the next lexicographic permutation, and what found independently by hand has been found by others, consider [OEIS A217626](https://oeis.org/A217626)

> A217626       First differences of [A215940](https://oeis.org/A215940), or first differences of
>   permutations of (0,1,2,...,m-1) reading them as decimal numbers,
>   divided by 9 (with 10>=m, and m! > n).
>
> > 1, 9, 2, 9, 1, 78, 1, 19, 3, 8, 2, 77, 2, 8, 3, 19, 1, 78, 1, 9, 2, 9,
> >     1, 657, 1, 9, 2, 9, 1, 178, 1, 29, 4, 7, 3, 66, 2, 18, 4, 18, 2, 67,
> >     1, 19, 3, 8, 2, 646, 1, 19, 3, 8, 2, 67, 1, 29, 4, 7, 3, 176, 3, 7, 4,
> >     29, 1, 67, 2, 8, 3, 19, 1, 646, 2, 8, 3, 19, 1

Also of interest is that the graph of the specific multiples of `9` to derive all lexicographic permutations of a set can be found by computing only half `1/2` of the total permutations `+1`, as the declination slope is identical to the inclination slope of multiples of `9`, for example, given an input of the string `"abc"` or array `["a","b","c"]`, we only need to reach the inverted peak of the graph, that is `bca 120 3 18`, where the previously calculated values can be reversed and added to the current whole number, `120`, to generate the remainder of the lexicographic permutations

```
abc 012 0
acb 021 1 9
bac 102 2 81
bca 120 3 18
cab 201 4 81
cba 210 5 9

 /\/\
/    \
```

### Errata

This challenge is not to determine the most efficient algorithm to calculate permutation `9!`, as, again, adding `9` to a whole number to reach that goal can be outperformed by swapping values or other method, as demonstrated at the accepted at the first SO link above.

This challenge is to derive the most efficient method of determining the next lexicographic permutation by calculating the next multiple of `9` that meets the above listed criteria, preferably *directly* using math, if possible.

The reason am posting this question **here and now** is because was *reminded* by the graph of the peaks (particularly the third item) in this question [Different combinations possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173081/different-combinations-possible)

> **Just to give a visual example, they are the following:**
>
> ```
>    /\     /\      /\/\
> /\/  \   /  \/\  /    \
> ```

that in spite of performing various calculations using the index of the `!n` within the resulting array of permutations, e.g.,

```js
var n = N = 1234;
var res = [9,81,18,81,9,702,9,171,27,72,18,693,18,72,27,171,9,702,9,81,18,81,9].map((x)=>n=n+x);
// try to determine the rate of growth
var j = res.map((x)=>x/N);

console.log(res, j);
```

```js
var tryStuff = 1234*(4321/1234);
console.log(tryStuff, (4321/1234));
```

am still vexed by and have not been able to independently determine the mathematical formula to derive the next lexicographic permutation *directly* without adding `9` multiple times to reach the required number; or if that is even mathematically possible for any input set from `2!` through `9!`. That is, this code

```js
function getNextLexicographicPermutation(arr) {

  for (var l = 1, i = k = arr.length; l < i; k *= l++);

  function checkDigits(min, max, n) {
    var digits = 0;
    while (n) {
      d = (n % 10);
      n = n / 10 >> 0;

      if (d < min || d > max || (digits & (1 << d)))
        return false;
      else
        digits |= 1 << d;
    }
    return true;
  }

  var len = arr.length,
    idx = arr.map(function(_, index) {
      return index
    }),
    p = 9,
    min = 0,
    max = len - 1,
    last = Number(idx.slice().reverse().join("")),
    curr = Number(idx.join("")),
    res = [curr],
    diff = [],
    result = [],
    next, times = 0;

  while (res.length < (k / 2) + 1) {
    ++times;
    next = (curr += p);
    if (checkDigits(min, max, next)) res[res.length] = next;
    curr = next;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    var item = res[i];
    item = String(item).split("").map(Number);
    item = (item.length < arr.length ? [0].concat(item) : item)
      .map(function(index) {
        return arr[index]
      }).filter(Boolean);
    result.push(item)
  }

  res.reduce(function(a, b) {
    diff.push(b - a);
    return b
  });

  for (var i = 0, curr = res[res.length - 1], n = diff.length - 2; result.length < k; i++, n--) {
    curr = curr + diff[n];
    result.push(
      String(curr).split("")
      .map(function(index) {
        return arr[index]
      })
    );
  }
  return [result, diff, res, times];
}

var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

console.log(getNextLexicographicPermutation(arr));
```

which generates the second half-1 of the permutations from the first half+1 of the permutations checks if the next whole number meets the necessary conditions `210` times for an input array of `["a","b","c","d"]` which has a resulting `.length` of `24`. Ideally, we want to generate `24` lexicographic permutations using only `12` or `13` checks; or no checks at all, by determining the irrational number or other mathematical algorithm which will *directly* calculate (or approximate close enough to determine the next multiple of `9`) the next whole number which meets the necessary criteria.

Kindly disregard the length of this post, as am trying to include as much information as consider relevant to the inquiry.

### Rules

This challenge must use the number `9` (addition, multiplication, division, other mathematical operation) to determine the next lexicographic permutation using the indexes of the current lexicographic permutation converted to a whole number, ideally, in a single operation, else in the least amount of operations necessary to achieve the expected result.

Again, this challenge is not asking how to code *the* most efficient code which determines the next lexicographic permutation, but what is *the* most efficient approach is using only the number `9` and math to generate the permutations.

Since we can get the first and last lexicographic permutations by reversing the indexes of the input array, that is not counted as an operation within the program.

### Input

An array or sting having `.length` less than or equal to `9!`.

### Output

Lexicographically sorted array of permutations of input.

### Task

Remaining within the Rules above, determine a mathematical algorithm which directly generates the next lexicographic permutation using only the current indexes of the original input or current permutation. Ideally, directly, without having to add `9` in multiple operations until the listed criteria is met, that is, we want a single algorithm to calculate that we need to add `81` to `132` to get the sum `213` and add `702` to `321` to get the sum `1023` and so forth. Explain the math in the algorithm. **Note:** The requirement might not be possible. If that is the case, explain why.

Comment: 1. As I commented elsewhere, it's hard to separate the core challenge from the fluff. 2. I assume there's a typo in the "Input" section, because an array of the permutations of 9! elements would take more memory than is physically possible in this universe.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Kindly indicate specifically what content in the question that you are referring to. From perspective here, there is no "fluff" in the question. No, there is no typo in the "Input" section. The algorithm MUST be true for `9!`->`362880` if true for `4!`->`24`. We can check the result of the algorithm by incremental sections and by hand. Simplified core challenge: Find the multiple of `9` required to precisely equal the next `p` lexicographic permutation (as a whole number) from current `p` number in least math computations.

Comment: @PeterTaylor E.g., if we have input `['a','b','c']` we ignore values and "see" `12`, `012` (or, as described at this question for simplification 1-based indexing `123`). The next lexicographic permutation is one computation `123+(9*1)=132` from we can "see" `['a','c','b']`.  In JavaScript we could even use `Math.pow(9,1)`, but that would be a false-positive for a method or pattern to use, because the next multiple is `132+(9*9)=213` (we can "see" `['b','a','c']`). How to get from `132` to `213` without _adding_ `9` _nines times_ (Task: least mathematical computations in this step) to `132`?

Comment: Should we take an array of items (`['a','b','c']`), an array of indices (`[1,2,3]`) or its value converted to decimal (`123`) as input? And what should be the output -- `132`, `['1','3','2']` or `9`?

Comment: @user202729 The input is a decimal derived from the first lexicographic permutation or an array of items from which the decimal will be derived; e.g., `123` from `['a','b','c']`, or `123456789` (1-based indexing) or `012345678` (0-based indexing) derived from `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i" ]`. The maximum number is the reverse order of the decimal number, `987654321` or `876543210`, which is the last lexicographic permutation (as a decimal number) of the input number or array `[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]` (0-based) or `[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` (1-based).

Comment: @user202729 We can derive all lexicographic permutations of input up to `9!` by adding `9` to the first lexicographic permutation as decimal and following the two conditions at the question; that is, by adding `9` to the initial decimal number where no duplicate numbers are found within the resulting number and each number is found within the original decimal number. Example `"abc"`->`curr=123`->`123+9=132`->`"acb"`; `curr` becomes `132`. We are trying to reduce the number of additions to meet the two conditions by creating a formula to determine the _precise_ number of `9`'s to add to `curr`.

Comment: @user202729 Is the question clear to you now?

Comment: @user202729 The output is `n<=9!` permutations. We can already achieve that by the code at the question. However the challenge is to reduce the mathematical steps required to reach the result consider _"How to get from `132` to `213` without adding `9` nines times (Task: least mathematical computations in this step) to `132`"_. When `curr` is `132`, we do not necessarily know that we will have to add `9` to `132` nine times (`81`) to reach the sum `213`. We find that out now by nine computations, adding. The challenge is to reach the sum `213` using what we have in less than nine computations.

Comment: @user202729 There are other mathematical relationships between the indexes of the lexicographically sorted permutations. For example, if we have the input `['a','b','c']` or `"abc"`, when we ignore the values, using 1-based indexing, we can "see" `123` at index `1`. `123+90=213` our lexicographically sorted permutation at index `3`, `132` at index `2` is `132+90=231`; max number is always input reversed. We only need to find `132` (3 operations) to derive all `6` permutations, as the declination slope of `[123,132,213]` is the reverse order of each number; this relationship differs for `1234`.

Comment: What is `n` in that case? /// Consider a specific example. If the input is `132` (1-indexing) what should the output be?

Comment: @user202729 The output is always `n!` lexicographic permutations. We already are able to achieve that. Whether the input is `123` or `132` makes no substantial difference here; we "see" that `132` is greater than its constituent parts, `123` and thus know that we are at index `2` (1-indexing), `321` is always the max, and `n!` is `6`. What this challenge is asking is how to use this specific method of determining permutations, that is, adding `9` to the indexes as a whole number until the listed conditions are met, in less mathematical operations that is currently being used - simple addition.

Comment: Let me see. So, if `132` is given, the output should be `[123,132,213,231,312,321]`, but with a restriction -- only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division is allowed. Correct?

Comment: @user202729 There is no restriction on the mathematical methods which can be used. You can use calculus if that will generate `132` _from_ `123` in the least amount of calculations - using `9` within the calculations. If you can use mathematical relationships between the expected resulting set which uses other numbers, then those methods should be described in detail. The code at the question uses only the number `9` to add to the indexes represented as a whole number, though for some `90` or `711` could be used. The challenge is to use the least number of _total_ math computations.

Comment: @user202729 We are trying to generate the next lexicographic permutation using only 1) the _current_ permutation; 2) the maximum possible number (our last permutation); 3) mathematics; as our resources. We begin with a number less than `321` and know that our first permutation must be `123`, our last `321`, and that between `321` and `123` there are relationships between the numbers which allow us to derive each number that meets our criteria. In the code at the question `9` is suitable to achieve that goal by adding `9` to the number where the sum contains no duplicate and only input numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Qwixx KoTH

In this King of the Hill, our bots will be playing [Qwixx](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/131260/qwixx). In Qwixx each player will try to get as many points by picking the sum of two dices and marking that number on your own scoresheet. The scoresheet has four rows with different colors (red, yellow, green, blue) with numbers ranging from 2 to 12, where green and blue have the numbers ranked in descending order. You can only mark out a number if you haven't marked a number to the right of it, i.e. after marking `red 3` you cannot mark `red 2` anymore.

#### Rules

All of the rules of Qwixx are:

- Red and yellow have numbers 2, 3, ..., 12, and a padlock.
- Green and blue have numbers 12, 11, ..., 2, and a padlock.
- There are 6 dices: red, yellow, green, blue and two white dices.
- On your turn you will throw all the dices, except for deleted ones.
- Everyone can mark one number on one color equal to the sum of the white dices. Also if it is not your turn.
- If it is your turn, you can also mark one number in a specific color, with the sum of one colored dice and one white dice. The colored dice that you pick denotes in which color you need to mark the number.
- You can only mark numbers to the right of already marked numbers.
- The last number can only be marked if you have already marked at least 5 numbers before. If you do this, you will automatically also mark the padlock, which will give you extra points. If you do this, that colored dice is not thrown anymore and nobody can mark a number in that color. This dice is deleted from the game (thrown as 0).
- Only on your turn you need to mark at least one number. If you don't do this, you will automatically mark a penalty box, which costs you 5 points.
- The amount of points is equal to the sum of 1 up to the amount of marks in each color, minus 5 times the amount of penalties. I.e.: 4 in red, 3 in green and 2 penalties is `4+3+2+1 + 3+2+1 = 16 - 2 * 5 = 6` points.
- Each turn is simultanouesly.
- The game ends when the second dice is deleted or when a scoresheet contains 4 penalties.

#### Tournament

The tournament rules are as follows:

- The tournament consists of `10000 * amount of bots` games.
- Each game will be played with 5 random bots, in a randomized order.
- If multiple bots end up with the same amount of points in one game, each bot gets a win.
- The winner of the tournament is the bot who has the highest win percentage.

#### Bots

The bot needs to be defined in Python and needs to have two functions:

- `__init__(self, index)` with the index in `scoresheets`, so that you know which `scoresheet` is yours
- `turn(self, scoresheets, dices, my_turn)`, with the current `scoresheets`, the `dices` of this turn and a boolean being `True` when it is your turn. This function needs to return a tuple of two tuples containing `(color, number)` with what your bot wants to mark, where the first tuple is for the white dices, and the second tuple only if its your turn.

The simplest bot can be defined as:

```py
class DoNothing:
    def __init__(self, index):
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, dices, my_turn):
        return ([],[])
```

Which does absolutely nothing.

A randomized bot that tries to always mark something when possible is:

```py
class RandomAllowedCombinations:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, dices, my_turn):
        (any_combs, turn_combs) = scoresheets[self.index].allowed_combinations(my_turn, dices)

        any_comb = []
        if any_combs:
            any_comb = any_combs[random.randint(0, len(any_combs)-1)]

        turn_comb = []
        if my_turn and turn_combs:
            turn_comb = turn_combs[random.randint(0, len(turn_combs)-1)]

        return (any_comb, turn_comb)
```

This also shows some of the utility functions: you can use `scoresheets[self.index].allowed_combinations(my_turn, dices)` to check what you can mark with the white dices, and if its your turn with one of the colored dices as well.

Both classes (`Dices` and `Scoresheet`) have several utility functions. You can check themselves to improve your bot. Note that `Dices` also contains the indices for each color. And the value of a dice is 0 if it is deleted (i.e. when someone in the game marked the last number and thus the padlock in one of the previous turns).

#### Controller

The controller contains 5 example bots. These will not be used in the tournament, unless there are too few participants.

```py
import random
import numpy

### Bots ###
class DoNothing:
    def __init__(self, index):
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, d, my_turn):
        return ([],[])

class AlwaysWhitesInRed:
    def __init__(self, index):
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, d, my_turn):
        return ((d.red, d.dices[d.white1] + d.dices[d.white2]),[])

class AlwaysBlueOnlyTurn:
    def __init__(self, index):
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, d, my_turn):
        return ([],(d.blue, d.dices[d.blue] + d.dices[d.white2]))

class RandomAllowedCombinations:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, dices, my_turn):
        (any_combs, turn_combs) = scoresheets[self.index].allowed_combinations(my_turn, dices)

        any_comb = []
        if any_combs:
            any_comb = any_combs[random.randint(0, len(any_combs)-1)]

        turn_comb = []
        if my_turn and turn_combs:
            turn_comb = turn_combs[random.randint(0, len(turn_combs)-1)]

        return (any_comb, turn_comb)

class RandomButOnlyOwnTurn:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        return
    def turn(self, scoresheets, dices, my_turn):
        (any_combs, turn_combs) = scoresheets[self.index].allowed_combinations(my_turn, dices)

        turn_comb = []
        if my_turn and turn_combs:
            turn_comb = turn_combs[random.randint(0, len(turn_combs)-1)]

        return ([], turn_comb)

### Classes ###
class Dices:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dices = []
        self.deleted = []
        self.red = 0
        self.yellow = 1
        self.green = 2
        self.blue = 3
        self.white1 = 4
        self.white2 = 5
        self.colors = [self.red, self.yellow, self.green, self.blue]
        self.whites = [self.white1, self.white2]
        self.diff_dices = self.colors + self.whites

    def roll_dice(self):
        self.dices = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for i in range(6):
            if i not in self.deleted:
                self.dices[i] = random.randint(1, 6)

    def delete_dice(self, color):
        if not color in self.deleted:
            self.deleted.append(color)
        return len(self.deleted) > 1

    def combinations(self):
        combs = [(color, white) for color in self.colors for white in self.whites]

        any_combs = [(color, self.dices[self.white1] + self.dices[self.white2]) for color in self.colors if self.dices[color] >= 1]
        turn_combs = [(color, self.dices[color] + self.dices[white]) for (color, white) in combs if self.dices[color] >= 1]

        return (any_combs, turn_combs)

class Game:
    def __init__(self, bots):
        self.bots = [bots[i](i) for i in range(len(bots))]
        self.scoresheets = [Scoresheet() for i in self.bots]
        self.dices = Dices()
        self.turn_number = 2

    def round(self):
        self.dices.roll_dice()
        (any_combs, turn_combs) = self.dices.combinations()

        finished = False

        for i, bot in enumerate(self.bots):
            my_turn = self.whos_turn() == i
            moves = bot.turn(self.scoresheets, self.dices, my_turn)
            deleted_colors = self.scoresheets[i].mark(moves, my_turn, any_combs, turn_combs, self.dices)
            if deleted_colors:
                finished = finished or any([self.dices.delete_dice(deleted_color) for deleted_color in deleted_colors]) 
            finished = finished or self.scoresheets[i].too_many_penalties()

        self.turn_number += 1

        return finished

    def whos_turn(self):
        return (self.turn_number - 1) % len(self.bots)

    def runGame(self):
        finished = False
        while not finished:
            finished = self.round()
        #for i, scoresheet in enumerate(self.scoresheets):
            #print self.bots[i], scoresheet.values, scoresheet.penalties, scoresheet.points()

class Scoresheet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.red = []
        self.yellow = []
        self.green = []
        self.blue = []
        self.penalties = 0
        self.values = [self.red, self.yellow, self.green, self.blue]

    def points(self):
        points = self.penalties * -5
        for color in self.values:
            points += sum(range(len(color)+1))
        return points

    def allowed_combinations(self, my_turn, dices):
        (any_combs, turn_combs) = dices.combinations()
        any_combs = [(color, number) for (color, number) in any_combs if self.allowed(color, number, any_combs, dices)]
        turn_combs = [(color, number) for (color, number) in turn_combs if self.allowed(color, number, turn_combs, dices)]

        if not my_turn:
            turn_combs = []

        return (list(set(any_combs)), list(set(turn_combs)))

    def allowed(self, color, number, combs, d):
        if color not in d.deleted:
            if (color, number) in combs:
                if color == d.red or color == d.yellow:
                    if not self.values[color] or max(self.values[color]) < number:
                        if number < 12 or self.end_number(color, number, d):
                            return True
                if color == d.green or color == d.blue:
                    if not self.values[color] or min(self.values[color]) > number:
                        if number > 2 or self.end_number(color, number, d):
                            return True
        return False

    def end_number(self, color, number, d):
        if len(self.values[color]) > 5:
            return (number == 2 and (color == d.green or color == d.blue)) or (number == 12 and (color == d.red or color == d.yellow))
        return False

    def mark_one(self, color, number, combs, deleted, d):
        if self.allowed(color, number, combs, d):
            self.values[color].append(number)
            if self.end_number(color, number, d):
                self.values[color].append(0)
                deleted.append(color)
        return deleted

    def mark(self, moves, my_turn, any_combs, turn_combs, d):
        beforePoints = self.points()

        deleted = []
        if moves[0]:
            deleted = self.mark_one(moves[0][0], moves[0][1], any_combs, deleted, d)
        if my_turn and moves[1]:
            deleted = self.mark_one(moves[1][0], moves[1][1], turn_combs, deleted, d)

        if my_turn and beforePoints == self.points():
            self.penalties += 1

        return deleted

    def too_many_penalties(self):
        return self.penalties >= 4

class Qwixx:
    def __init__(self, bots, bots_per_game):
        self.bots = bots
        self.games = [0 for i in range(len(self.bots))]
        self.points = [0 for i in range(len(self.bots))]
        self.wins = [0 for i in range(len(self.bots))]
        self.amountOfGames = len(bots) * 1000
        self.bots_per_game = bots_per_game

    def run_tournament(self):
        for g in range(1, self.amountOfGames + 1):
            bot_indices = numpy.random.choice(range(len(self.bots)), self.bots_per_game, replace=False)
            bots_this_game = [self.bots[i] for i in bot_indices]

            game = Game(bots_this_game)
            game.runGame()

            maxPoints = max([game.scoresheets[i].points() for i in range(len(bot_indices))])
            for bot_index_game, bot_index_total in enumerate(bot_indices):
                points = game.scoresheets[bot_index_game].points()
                self.points[bot_index_total] += points
                self.games[bot_index_total] += 1
                if points == maxPoints:
                    self.wins[bot_index_total] += 1
                    print "GAME", g, "is",  self.wins[bot_index_total], "th win by", self.bots[bot_index_total].__name__

    def tournament(self):
        self.run_tournament()

        win_rates = {i: self.wins[i] / float(self.games[i]) for i in range(len(self.bots))}
        format_result = '{:>30}: {:.4f}  {:>6} {:>8} {:>8}' 
        format_header = '{:>30}: {:>6}  {:>6} {:>8} {:>8}' 
        print(format_header.format('Name', 'Win %', 'Wins', 'Games', 'Points'))
        for j, i in enumerate(sorted(win_rates, key=lambda i: win_rates[i], reverse=True)):
            print(format_result.format(self.bots[i].__name__, win_rates[i], self.wins[i], self.games[i], self.points[i]))

### List of all bots ###
all_bots = [DoNothing, BadRandom, RandomAllowedCombinations, Random50, RandomButOnlyOwnTurn]

### Run tournament ###
Qwixx(all_bots, 5).tournament()
```

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

#### Sandbox

- If someone can check my Python programming capabilities that would be great. I'm no native Python programmer.
- There are quite some rules. Maybe I should simplify it? These are the official rules, but for example I could change that even on your turn you can only move once instead of twice.
- This is my first challenge, so any feedback is welcome.
- Note that I have not yet tested my controller thoroughly, I will do this before posting it as an actual challenge.

Comment: 1. Simplification of the rules is definitely needed.  This post is hard to understand and even harder to come up with strategies about.  Under "Rules", I'd immediately start explaining the actions bots can perform and their consequenses.  2. Why are there two types of turns (only-white turn, vs color turn)? How does this affect strategies? 3. What's the purpose of marking the last box to prevent other players?  How does this affect strategies?  4. I don't understand the scoring, please expound.

Comment: 1. It's not entirely clear to me whether on my turn I can choose to make my "colour mark" before my "white mark" if they're on the same colour. 2. *Dice* is an irregular noun in English: the singular is *die* and the plural is *dice*. 3. `10000 * number of bots` games is a lot, so it's going to be slow to run the tournament, but at the same time with 13 bots it's too few to run every possible combination once. This might need a more complicated tournament structure with elimination rounds.

Answer (score 0):

**Roulette Bots II**

Last week I posted [Roulette Bots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173209/robot-roulette-high-stakes-robot-gambling), which was a lot of fun. I think the basic format has potential to be even more interesting, so I've been shopping some tweaks in my head and I'd like to hear feedback before I give it another shot. In a nutshell, the first iteration of the game was as follows:

Everyone starts with 100 hp. Each round, 2 players are chosen at random from the pool of contestants who have not yet competed in that round. Both players pick a number between 0 and their current hp, and reveal those numbers at the same time. The player who chose the lower number immediately dies. The other player subtracts their chosen number from their remaining hp and goes on to the next round.

From the bracket of contestants, 2 are chosen at random. They face off, and one or both of them dies. A player dies if:

1. They choose a number smaller than that of their opponent
2. Their hp drops to or below zero
3. They tie three times in a row with their opponent

In the case of ties, both players simply generate new numbers, up to 3 times. After the faceoff, the survivor (if any) is moved to the pool for the next round, and the process repeats until we have exhausted the current round pool. If there is an odd number in the pool, then the odd one out moves on to the next round for free.

Players were given as input their own hp, and their opponent's complete betting history for that round. The idea being that players must balance resource consumption and long-term performance against the danger of dying right now if they don't bid high enough.

There are two things I'd like feedback on:

1. The minimal set of restrictions on user submissions required to make an interesting game without limiting creativity
2. Format tweaks that will allow for more creativity within the scope of the rules

The rule set I ended up on for the last game was that you were not allowed to take any action that unambiguously identified your opponent. This was for the purpose of avoiding things like players simply reading the stack to figure out exactly who their opponent was, since then you can simply simulate your opponent and more or less guarantee a win. While clever, it's doesn't really fit the spirit of the game. So the first question is whether or not there is a less restrictive rule that could be applied, or if someone can see a glaring loophole in that rule which would allow for game-breaking behavior in future versions of a similar game.

On the subject of format tweaks, the biggest issue I found with the game was that with a relatively small pool of contestants, very little history was actually generated and so bots that tried to use history to predict opponent guesses fared poorly overall. The first tweak I had in mind was to bootstrap a very large (256 or 512, maybe) initial tournament by random resampling of existing bots so that there would be many rounds and a good history pool to work with by the end of it.

Coupled with the larger pool, I intend to change the scoring system to reward longevity, to encourage more careful resource management, as compared to the previous game which rewarded just living through the first round. Something like making participating in the nth rounds worth n points, so that a player which survives to the nth round gets n(n-1)/2 points total. This puts more stringent constraints on resource management, since you need to survive a lot of rounds to do well. I'd probably bump the starting hp up to 1000, so that there is a bit more room to refine bets. and to make ties even less likely.

Second, there were a couple of attempts to make teams of bots that communicated via betting history in order to feed easy wins to one of them. I like the idea, but but because of the limited options presented by betting history they didn't fare very well. I am considering having bots exchange a "greeting" before each fight - a string or integer which they send to their opponent before battling, which could be used to identify teammates or clones of yourself. Does it add enough possibilities to gameplay to be worth the extra effort? Since with a resampled population you would likely be competing with yourself fairly regularly, having a way to recognize yourself (while at the same time avoiding others being able to recognize you from your greeting) seems like it could be interesting, but I worry that it will just degenerate into people updating their greeting at the last second to avoid other people using them, which would make it pointless to use the greeting to recognize opponents and make a lot of work for me. Can anyone suggest a good way to handle this? I want a way for people to recognize an opponent as probably (but not certainly) friendly without making it a game of "who updates last".

Feedback on the proposed gameplay tweaks, or ideas for others that I have not considered, would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not allow the "feed" strategy.  We want all of the bots to be competitive, and the feeder bots aren't competitive, and creates an unfair advantage to individual bots (hmm...I wonder who will win 3v1).  I also am not a fan of "send a message" actions:  They either don't work or they make abuse possible.  (The only exception is if you are making a team-based KotH) Scoring based on longevity is a good idea.  If you want a longer history, you can also do a lives-based mechanic where a player has 3 lives.  If they choose the lower number 3 times, *then* they are out of the tournament.

Comment: @NathanMerrill the idea for the feeding was that if I have to have multiple copies of each bot in the tournament to get a large pool, then it would be useful to recognize yourself. By default, you will always have "teammates" as long as resampling happens. But I understand the objection. How would lives work, practically? If a bot bids lower, how would I handle that? Ignore the result up to 3 times, and just let them through to the next round without cost to either player?

Comment: Oh, I like the idea of feeding copies of your bot. Perhaps giving them a single boolean variable that indicates if it's a clone or not (or something along those lines?).  If both both Bot A and B have multiple lives, they would both have their HP removed, but the one that bid lower would have a life removed.  Perhaps "life" is the wrong term here:  Maybe they get a "strike", and 3 strikes and you are out.

Comment: Actually!  If you have multiple clones of a bot, there's an easier solution than a 3-strike system:  Simply give the opponent the entire history of all of the clones.

Comment: I think if I used the 3 strike system what would happen is that everyone would just bid 0 twice in a row to get into the later rounds with full hp and go from there. Realistically I can't stop the feeding strategy, since you can use betting history to set up a recognizable pattern, so I think it's better to build it into the game somehow. Simply telling people if it's a clone is an option, but then it would just advance one to the next round for free without generating a meaningful bid history data point, so why have the clones in the first place? The entire history of clones is a neat idea...

Comment: You tell people if they are playing against their own clone.  There's not like an "original bot" or a "clone bot".  You simply have a variable that is true if it is `Bot 1 vs Bot 1` and false if it is `Bot 1 vs Bot 2`.  You are right that there are no systematic ways to stop feeding, but we have rules against that on SE, and so you can use human judgement to disallow those bots.

Comment: I know what you mean. But if I tell them that, then they get to advance deterministically with a bet of 1, which is not a useful data point for anyone else predicting their behavior. I would like to find a solution that forces at least a meaningful bet (or that they have to take the risk of mistaken identity to make the 1-bet). If they know for certain they are facing a clone, then there is no value to having clones at all, since their purpose was to make a longer tournament with more history to use in predictions. But I realize as I say this that the "message passing" idea doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah.  Perhaps you setup the tournament so that clones never actually fight each other.  These battles aren't interesting, and only hurt the bot that randomly got assigned itself.  The existence of clones would solely be to have a longer history.

Comment: The only really sound way to avoid the *who updates last* problem is to host it in such a way that people can't see their competitors' code - i.e. somewhere other than PPCG. On this site you'll always have people special-casing specific opponents.

Comment: @PeterTaylor probably true. Perhaps I could collect submissions by some other means and just ask players to put a placeholder answer which they can edit with code after the deadline. Would that be allowed? I'd have to keep the controller private, and maybe provide a suite of unit tests that entries should pass before submission.

Comment: Something vaguely similar has been done once (a Kolmogorov-complexity question where OP asked people to post a hash of their code, and then after the deadline to post their actual code, so that people couldn't just port someone else's answer to a golfier language), but it's a lot of hassle. Really when you're having to fight the site's design that much, you may as well not bother and just accept that some challenges don't work here.

Comment: Looking at what happened with your previous challenge, though, I would suggest requiring that answers be self-contained so that the deletion of a function defined in someone else's answer won't break them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor fair enough, that does seem like a lot of unnecessary work. I'll shop the format a bit more and see if I can come up with something a little simpler. Disallowing interaction between entries is certainly doable, but having people post lat-second updates will always be a problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## Is it a valid snooker break?

In snooker, the objective is to score as many points as possible by potting two types of balls: red balls, 15 of them, each valued 1 point, and colour balls, 6 of them, valued 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 points. A *break* is a sequence of potted balls. The balls must be potted in a predetermined order: the break must start with potting a red ball, then a colour ball and continued with alternating in potting red and colour balls until all of the red balls are potted, then potting colour balls in ascending order of their values (if all of the red balls have already been potted, start with the colour ball with the lowest value). However, if a *free ball* is declared after an opponent's foul, the break may start with any ball, replacing the ball that should be usually potted first (red if some red balls are still on the table, colour with the lowest value if all reds are potted).

Your task is to determine if the given sequence of balls adheres to the rules mentioned above.

### Input

A list of integers representing values of snooker balls. The list will not be empty.

### Output

A truthy value if the list is a valid snooker break and falsey if it isn't.

### Test cases

Truthy:

```
6
1,7
2,5
2,3,4
1,5,1,5,1
1,3,1,5,1,4
6,4,5
5,2,1,4,1,6,1,6
1,6,2,3,4,5,6,7
3,2,3,4,5,6,7
4,4,1
5,6,1,7
1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,2,3,4,5,6,7 //"maximum break"
7,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Falsey:

```
1,1
4,4,4
4,2,3,1
1,2,3
5,1,7,1
2,5,6,7 //2 is already off the table
5,4,2,3
1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,2,3,4,5,6,7     //one red too many
7,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,1,7,2,3,4,5,6,7 //as well as here
```

## To sandbox:

I am thinking about including lists with values out of range of snooker balls' values (less than 1 or greater than 7) in which cases the result should be falsey. As this is a decision problem, I think that these cases should be covered as well.

Comment: Maybe you can let the submissions assume that only a list of [1-7]s are inputted. This would be more flexible for the submissions to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Cologne Phonetics

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_phonetics):
Cologne phonetics is a phonetic algorithm which assigns to words a sequence of digits, the phonetic code. The aim of this procedure is that identical sounding words have the same code assigned to them. The algorithm can be used to perform a similarity search between words. For example, it is possible in a name [collection?] to find entries like "Meier" under different spellings such as "Maier", "Mayer" or "Mayr".

The Cologne phonetics matches each letter of a word to a digit between 0 and 8. To select the appropriate digit, at most one adjacent letter is used as context.

#### Procedure:

Processing of a word is done in three steps:

1. Encode letter by letter from left to right according to the conversion rules below.
2. Remove all digits occurring more than once next to each other.
3. Remove all code "0" except at the beginning

#### Conversion rules

- **A, E, I, J, O, U, Y** become 0
- **H** becomes nothing
- **B** becomes 1
- **P** becomes 1, unless it's before H
- **D, T** become 2, unless they're before C, S, Z
- **F, V, W** become 3
- **P** becomes 3, if it's before H
- **G, K, Q** become 4
- **C** becomes 4 in initial position before A, H, K, L, O, Q, R, U, X
- **C** becomes 4, if it's before A, H, K, O, Q, U, X, except after S, Z
- **X** becomes 48, unless it's after C, K, Q
- **L** becomes 5
- **M, N** become 6
- **R** becomes 7
- **S, Z** become 8
- **C** becomes 8, if it's after S, Z
- **C** becomes 8 in initial position except before A, H, K, L, O, Q, R, U, X
- **C** becomes 8, if it's not before A, H, K, O, Q, U, X
- **D, T** become 8, if they're before C, S, Z
- **X** becomes 8, if it's after C, K, Q

### Challenge

Implement a program or a function that takes a single string as input and returns the phonetic code according to the rules stated above. You may choose your own output format, but keep in mind that the expected output may have leading zeros. The input string is guaranteed to match `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/`, this means it may contain characters from the lowercase and uppercase alphabet, as well as spaces.

### Test cases

```
Input                 Output

[empty string]        [empty]
Kolner Phonetik       45673624
Meier                 67
Mayer                 67
Augsburg              048174
Xanten                48626
Telephon              2356
Chemie                46
Muller Ludenscheid    65752682
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code for each language wins.

Comment: Related: [Soundex function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3119/56433)

Comment: What's the difference between "initial sound" and "initial position"?

Comment: Apparently there is none, from what I was able to find

Comment: Ideally there would be a test case for each conversion rule as the challenge is probably mainly about handling those edge cases in the rules.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement JavaScript's Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm.

[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

### Background

As many know, JavaScript has quite confusing equality rules and it's generally recommended to use `===` instead to avoid the weird corner cases that come with using `==`.

The logic behind the `==` operator is documented as "The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm" in the ECMAScript specification. For this particular question we will be implementing from the [ECMAScript 5.1 edition specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). The algorithm is documented in [section 11.9.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) of this specification.

### Task

Implement the abstract equality comparison algorithm in JavaScript without using `==` or `!=`.

### Input & output

The input is two variables. These variables can be anything that is not a [Reference type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7). The output is a truthy or falsy value that represents the result of performing the abstract equality comparison algorithm.

### Test Cases

Since there are a lot of edge cases, I took these test cases from the [test262 repository](https://github.com/tc39/test262/tree/master/test/language/expressions/equals).

Examples that return truthy values:

```
true == true
false == false
true == 1
false == "0"
0 == false
"1" == true
+0 == -0
-0 == +0
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY == -Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
1.0 == 1
"" == ""
" " == " "
"string" == "string"
1 == "1"
1.100 == "+1.10"
255 == "0xff"
0 == ""
"-1" == -1
"-1.100" == -1.10
"5e-324" == 5e-324
undefined == undefined
void 0 == undefined
undefined == eval("var x")
undefined == null
null == void 0
null == null
{ var x, y; x = {}; y = x; x == y; } // two variables pointing to same object
new Boolean(true) == true
new Number(1) == true
new String("1") == true
true == new Boolean(true)
true == new Number(1)
true == new String("+1")
new Boolean(true) == 1
new Number(-1) == -1
new String("-1") == -1
1 == new Boolean(true)
-1 == new Number(-1)
-1 == new String("-1")
new Boolean(true) == "1"
new Number(-1) == "-1"
new String("x") == "x"
"1" == new Boolean(true)
"-1" == new Number(-1)
"x" == new String("x")
{valueOf: function() {return 1}} == true
{valueOf: function() {return 1}, toString: function() {return 0}} == 1
{valueOf: function() {return 1}, toString: function() {return {}}} == "+1"
{valueOf: function() {return "+1"}, toString: function() {throw "error"}} == true
{toString: function() {return "+1"}} == 1
{valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return "+1"}} == "+1"
true == {valueOf: function() {return 1}}
1 == {valueOf: function() {return 1}, toString: function() {return 0}}
"+1" == {valueOf: function() {return 1}, toString: function() {return {}}}
true == {valueOf: function() {return "+1"}, toString: function() {throw "error"}}
1 == {toString: function() {return "+1"}}
"+1" == {valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return "+1"}}
```

Examples that return falsy values:

```
true == false
false == true
Number.NaN == true
Number.NaN ==  1
Number.NaN == Number.NaN
Number.NaN == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
Number.NaN == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
Number.NaN == Number.MAX_VALUE
Number.NaN == Number.MIN_VALUE
Number.NaN == "string"
Number.NaN == new Object()
true == Number.NaN
-1 == Number.NaN
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Number.NaN
Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Number.NaN
Number.MAX_VALUE == Number.NaN
Number.MIN_VALUE == Number.NaN
"string" == Number.NaN
new Object() == Number.NaN
1 == 0.999999999999
" " == ""
" string" == "string "
"1.0" == "1"
"0xff" == "255"
1 == "true"
"false" == 0
undefined == true
undefined == 0
undefined == "undefined"
undefined == {}
null == false
null == 0
null == "null"
null == {}
false == undefined
Number.NaN == undefined
"undefined" == undefined
{} == undefined
false == null
0 == null
"null" == null
{} == null
new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true)
new Number(1) == new Number(1)
new String("x") == new String("x")
new Object() == new Object()
new Boolean(true) == new Number(1)
new Number(1) == new String("1")
new String("1") == new Boolean(true)
{valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return "+1"}} == "1"
"1" == {valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return "+1"}}
```

Examples that throw an error:

```
{valueOf: function() {throw "error"}, toString: function() {return 1}} == 1 // throws "error"
{valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return {}}} == 1 // throws TypeError
1 == {valueOf: function() {throw "error"}, toString: function() {return 1}} // throws "error"
1 == {valueOf: function() {return {}}, toString: function() {return {}}} // throws TypeError
```

### Rules

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Sandbox Questions

- Is it ok that I am restricting the language to JavaScript? Should I allow languages that compile to JavaScript or have the types listed here?
- Have I got too many test cases here? Should I cut it down? Perhaps instead I could create a tio.run template which runs all the tests instead of listing them all out here.
- Is the requirement of not using `==` and `!=` strict enough? I feel that I want to avoid answers where some inbuilt function indirectly calls `==` and getting around it that way but I don't know how to enforce that.

Comment: I'd say the number of test cases is still acceptable, though creating a TIO template sounds like a good idea anyway.

Comment: We still can use `===` and `!==`, can't we?

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto yes

Comment: @CameronAavik Build a custom Javascript interpreter where calls to `==` errors out, then use that.

Comment: [Here's a link to a test framework in TIO](https://pastebin.com/XxndU7m1). I don't think it's possible to overload operators in javascript though

Comment: (for example when someone edits the interpreter to ban some features, see https://i.snag.gy/7ELPOt.jpg - the link "this branch" links to https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/7f74063321e6a49baa09e82ffffb9de0ff7bfd73 --- of course that's a lot of work, but that would make sure that people definitely don't cheat)

Answer (score 0):

## Find the pattern v2

I feel tired to do "find the pattern" exercise such as

```
1 2 3 4 (5)
1 2 4 8 (16)
1 2 3 5 8 (13)
```

Please write a program that finds the pattern for me.

Here, we define the pattern as a recurrence relation that fits the given input, with the smallest score. If there are multiple answers with the same smallest score, using any one is fine.

Let the \$k\$ first terms be initial terms for the recurrence relation, and the \$i\$'th term be \$f(i)\$ (\$i>k,i\in\mathbb N\$).

- A non-negative integer \$x\$ adds\$1\$ to the score
- The current index \$i\$ adds \$1\$ to the score
- `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` (round up, down, towards zero, go further to zero, as you decide) and `mod` (`a mod b` always equal to `a-b*(a/b)`) each add \$1\$ to the score
- For each initial term \$x\$, add \$1\$ to the score
- \$f(i-n)\$ (with \$n\le k\$) adds \$1\$ to the score. E.g. Using the latest value \$f(i-1)\$ add \$1\$ to the score, and there must be at least 1 initial term.
- Using parentheses to change the calculation order doesn't add anything to the score.

Samples:

```
input   -> [score]    expression(not optimized)
1 2 3 4     -> [1]    f(i) = i
1 2 4 8     -> [3]    f(1) = 1, f(i) = 2*f(i-1)
1 2 3 5 8   -> [5]    f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(i) = f(i-1)+f(i-2)
```

Lowest score for worse case wins. If tie, shortest program in each language wins. Your program should run in polynomial time.

If someone's score is lower than 4(currently reachable), the first lowest score will be accepted. (differ from winning criticia)

p.s. See history for v1 sandbox

Comment: I think the challenge could benefit from a precise defining grammar for a pattern. As it stands, I feel the set of all expressions that may fit is too vast.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Looks pretty precise to me. About "too vast" - there are only 6 bullets.

Comment: @user202729 I am unsure if _(round as you decide)_ includes the possibility of not rounding.

Comment: Should "3 0 0 0 0 0 ..." be "f(1)=3, f(n)=0", do "for the recurrence relation" work?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. -----

Comment: I don't understand the "fun fact"...

Comment: @user202729 Do you think it no fun or can't figure it out?

Comment: The latter. ----

Answer (score 0):

**Keyboard Row Shift**

Given an input string of characters, output the number of times we have to shift to another row while typing that string using a qwerty keyboard.

The input string will contain lower case alphabets,numbers and spaces.
The newline key(enter) must also be considered at the end (only at the end).
All shifts, from any row to any other will be considered as 1 shift only.

Layout:

```
1234567890
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl enter
zxcvbnm
space
```

Examples:

```
"sdkflsd" -> 0
"asdwexc" -> 3 # to end the string one enter has to pressed which is in the middle
"poierlkdjfpoeirldskjf" ->3
"123 jkjk" -> 2
"llsdkfj ldkfj" -> 2
"lkasdjmnbcv " -> 3
"jnjn 5" -> 6
```

This is **code-golf**, so shortest code wins.

Comment: You need some test cases that contain a space and numbers.  I'd also make it clear in your description that a shift can go any distance (going from the top row to the bottom is only 1 shift)

Comment: Done, @NathanMerrill

Comment: How flexible is input? Is uppercase OK? How about an array of character strings or even an array that mixes digits and character strings?

Comment: I have mentioned only lower case, input has to be string only not an array.

Answer (score 0):

## [Hack g-code parser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174873)

Comment: This could be seen as asking for malicious code, which is [not on-topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic).

Comment: @Laikoni this is not malicious\harmful code, because it don't causes harm to user. It is educational programming puzzle for white-hat hackers

Comment: @Laikoni `rm -rf /` is harmful, but `alert("pwned")` is not

Comment: Right, I think misread the challenge. If it is only about cracking this piece of code rather than actual implementations it's probably fine as a challenge. Any way, you need an objective winning criterion. [tag:code-golf] in the sense of "the shortest input to open the alert prompt" seems like a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Given a program in your language, generate another program that do exactly the same thing so every bytes in it are prime.

Shortest generator in every language win. No acception.

Nop in languages that only allow prime bytes are legit, but just don't post them(or make a community answer to put them)

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think that the idea of the challenge is not interesting and it should not be posted.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think that the idea is fine, but the challenge is unclear or needs fixing; in that case also leave a comment.

Comment: I made a small poll above ↑. I think the idea is interesting, and if it's poorly worded, the post can't be fixed without suggestions. Note that the challenge is already fully specified in the current state (task description, winning criteria), and it's impossible to give sample input/output to test programs (if you understand the challenge, you will see why).

Comment: Lots of languages quite rely on composite(not prime) bytes, so upvote this comment if you think it's too restrict

Comment: I think the idea is interesting, especially in languages like Jelly which can do most anything with small subsets of its character set. My main problem is: how much of the language do we have to support in the input to our generator? Many languages which are capable of this task have far too many possible instructions, etc., every one of which would need to be remapped to an all-prime version. Unless perhaps it's possible to simply generate any given string and execute it whilst using only prime bytes...

Comment: @ETHproductions I think a subset of an existing language can be considered another language?

Answer (score 0):

## Are these strings character wise translatable? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

#### Explanation with example:

Suppose you are given two strings of the same length, e.g. `"code"` and `"golf"`. Try to find a set of translation rules for characters (like *"All `c`s are replaced by `g`s"* , or `c -> g` for short) such that applying those rules on `"code"` yields `"golf"` and applying them to `"golf"` again yields `"code"`.

If there is such a set of translation rules, return a truthy value. Otherwise, if no such set can exist, return a falsy value.

In our example, the translation is possible with the rules `g -> c`, `d -> l`, `e -> f`, `c -> g`, `l -> d` and `f -> e`, so a truthy value should be returned.

However, if the two strings were `"code"` and `"meta"`, no such rules exist: To get from `"code"` to `"meta"` we need the rule `e -> a`, but to get from `"meta"` to `"code"` we would need `e -> o`. But `e` cannot be translated into two different characters! Therefore, a falsy value should be returned.

#### Consise mathy explanation:

Given two strings \$s\$ and \$t\$ of the same length \$n\$, decide whether the following relation is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection):
$$\{(s_i,t_i)\ |\ 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\} \cup \{(t_i,s_i)\ |\ 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\}$$
where \$s_i\$ denotes the \$i^{th}\$ character of string \$s\$.

#### Test cases

truthy:

```
"code", "golf"
"a", "a"
"abdabdcdacabcabd", "bacbacdcbdbadbac"
TODO: Add some more
```

falsy:

```
"code", "meta"
"aa", "ab"
"abc", "bca"
TODO: Add some more
```

Comment: This seems to be very similar to [Check if words are isomorphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50472/12012).

Comment: @Dennis It is definitely related. However, as far as I see most answers there work by creating some sort of fingerprint and checking whether it is the same for both inputs. This approach alone won't work here as you also need to check the symmetry of substitutions.

Comment: Not saying this makes it a dupe, because there might be golfier ways, but `s` and `t` are character wise translatable if and only if `s++t` and `t++s` are isomorphs.

Answer (score 0):

### Guess the Q in the code

A popular puzzle known to me as Codewords takes a Crossword-like grid and consistently replaces each letter with a code value, usually a number from 1 to 26, and the solver then has to work out which code value represents each letter. There are a number of approaches to this:

- There is a web site which can search for words given the pattern of repeating letters. Since repeated letters map to repeated code values, you can sometimes use the patten of repeated code values to determine the original word. For instance, the only word with the pattern `12.312..3...` is `churchwarden`.
- The puzzle normally provides a few of the letters to get you started. This may be enough to use a standard crossword solver to determine the original word. For instance, `.h...h...d..` would again point you to the word `churchwarden`.
- You could use frequency analysis to guess which letters are likely to be the popular letters such as `e` or `t`.
- You could look for common prefixes or suffixes such as `ally` or `ness`. (I picked those two as they have repeating letters which are easier to spot.)
- At least in all of the Codewords puzzles I have seen, `q` is always followed by a `u` and at least one letter. This means that if there is a code that is never the last or penultimate letter of a word, and always appears followed by the same code, then this could be a `q`.

However, checking all the codes to see how many distinct codes follow them is laborious. We need an automatic solution for this!

Please write a program or function that will guess which code(s) could represent the letter `q`. The input to the function will be an array of code values in a standard format. You will need to support 27 consistent distinct values, 26 for the codes themselves and a value for the background. These values can be integers but you could also use characters e.g. 26 letters and a space, in which case you can join them into strings, and even join the strings with a 28th character.

Your output will be all of the code values that have the property that, for each occurrence in the grid, either:

- The previous and following cells are background or would extend past the side of the grid, or
- There are two non-background following cells, and the first of those cells always contains the same value.

These rules apply in both the horizontal and vertical direction.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Examples needed, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

## User ranking in language

Challenge is:

- You need receive the input of "language". By "language" I mean the  at left of the comma in the Title of an answer on the present code-golf site.
- The source for the data are the answers posted here on code-golf site.
- You must present results in order. Decreasing or Increasing does not matter, it only needs to be one of those two.
- Output is a table of two columns {User, Upvotes}. Example: User enters `Java` and will obtain a list as the following:

`user_A    9523
user_B    6000
user_C     120`

Do not care very much about the output formatting as long it is clear the separation between the two columns and each line.

The will be no winner as it is a per language [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question.

Comment: "_The source for the data are the answers posted here on code-golf site._" The answers for this challenge, or ALL challenges on PPCG? And with your example, does this mean it searches for each user all answers given in Java, and sums their total upvote count? Also, do we differentiate `java`/`Java`/`Java 7`/`Java 10` etc as different inputs?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen 1. Yes, the scope is all answers on PPCG. 2. Yes, it is the total upvote account. 3. This is flexible on uppercase/lowercase, but not on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Concentration (or Memory or Match) is a game where players pick pairs of cards and try to find matches.  The rules are as follows:

1. Two of each number from 1 to N are added to the deck.
2. The deck is shuffled and placed face-down (hidden).
3. The player selects a card.  The card is revealed.
4. The player selects another card:  The card is revealed.
5. If the two cards are different numbers, then they are hidden again.
6. Steps 3 through 5 are repeated until all cards are revealed.

For example, lets say I have the following cards: `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`

Shuffle them: `1 4 3 1 4 3 2 2`

Place them face down: `X X X X X X X X`

The player will then select a card: `1 X X X X X X X`

And then another card: `1 X 3 X X X X X`

The numbers don't match, so we put the cards face down, and select another card: `X X X 1 X X X X`

The player remembers the position of the other 1: `1 X X 1 X X X X`

A match was found! These cards stay face-up, and we try again.

**The challenge is to do this with limited memory**.  You need to write a function/program that takes two parameters:

- A list of cards (with a constant value representing the hidden cards)
- 32 bytes of data.  This can be stored as a string, a large integer, etc.

Your function must use this data (and only this data) to select the next card to reveal, and then update the 32 bytes of data.  You may use a random number generator for free (as long as you do not use the seed to store data)

After the game is over, the game is scored by counting the number of times a card was revealed.

Below, I have provided a list of test cases.  Your score is the length of the first test case you complete with a score of greater than 2N+30 (N is the number of distinct cards).  Hard coding is not allowed, and your function should get a similar score with a different set of test cases.

```
2 1 4 0 0 3 3 4 2 1
3 0 4 3 2 0 4 1 1 2
1 3 2 2 4 3 0 4 0 1
2 2 0 4 4 1 1 3 3 0
3 2 1 1 0 0 4 3 4 2
3 2 0 4 2 5 1 1 0 3 5 4
4 5 0 3 2 5 3 1 0 2 1 4
4 1 2 0 2 5 1 3 3 5 0 4
2 3 2 4 3 1 0 5 4 0 1 5
3 1 4 0 2 2 5 3 1 5 4 0
1 4 0 5 2 3 6 1 0 3 5 4 6 2
6 3 5 3 1 2 1 5 2 4 4 6 0 0
5 6 0 0 5 3 1 1 2 4 6 2 4 3
1 1 6 2 2 4 0 4 5 5 6 0 3 3
3 4 6 4 6 2 5 0 0 1 3 5 2 1
3 2 6 4 1 5 7 4 3 7 0 2 6 0 1 5
7 3 1 0 6 2 3 6 4 1 5 7 5 0 4 2
2 6 5 4 2 5 0 0 7 3 1 4 6 7 3 1
4 7 5 0 6 3 0 1 3 1 7 2 6 4 2 5
4 7 5 1 4 3 2 6 0 6 7 3 2 5 1 0
7 6 5 4 5 0 1 3 8 3 4 0 1 8 6 2 2 7
2 4 1 8 7 4 6 5 3 8 1 3 7 2 0 6 5 0
6 4 7 8 5 1 4 3 0 8 3 5 2 6 1 2 7 0
3 8 0 6 4 0 1 5 2 7 7 1 5 3 2 6 8 4
7 1 8 8 3 1 3 4 5 4 6 2 2 0 0 7 6 5
9 4 1 5 7 3 4 1 6 3 9 7 2 2 0 5 6 0 8 8
2 2 6 1 8 6 5 7 3 4 5 0 9 3 0 9 7 4 8 1
7 4 3 5 2 7 1 1 0 0 9 8 6 8 3 6 2 9 4 5
1 6 3 2 7 0 7 9 1 5 0 4 8 6 3 8 9 5 2 4
8 4 5 9 9 3 0 5 6 2 2 7 0 4 1 8 7 1 3 6
1 7 0 2 1 3 8 8 6 9 2 3 4 5 6 5 10 4 7 10 0 9
3 5 10 3 5 1 9 10 1 2 0 4 0 8 6 7 8 4 9 2 6 7
9 1 7 8 2 8 9 10 2 0 6 6 5 3 5 1 10 0 4 7 3 4
7 8 2 9 8 0 0 9 3 1 5 2 4 1 3 10 4 10 5 6 6 7
3 7 9 5 1 2 8 6 3 6 4 0 10 1 2 7 10 9 8 4 5 0
7 6 9 6 2 5 5 0 11 9 3 10 8 3 4 8 4 2 11 1 1 10 7 0
10 2 8 5 11 3 4 2 6 11 4 7 10 9 8 9 1 1 6 0 5 7 3 0
4 0 7 7 4 6 11 8 3 9 3 2 5 1 11 10 8 2 9 5 0 10 1 6
10 8 8 0 0 3 7 4 11 10 9 2 4 5 6 9 5 6 7 1 1 11 3 2
1 7 0 8 9 10 4 5 10 6 5 1 4 3 7 2 0 9 3 11 8 2 6 11
3 7 10 11 1 5 10 2 9 3 8 11 5 9 6 0 0 4 12 12 4 8 1 6 2 7
0 11 9 11 2 9 10 6 5 2 7 0 12 1 10 7 6 8 3 3 4 1 12 5 8 4
3 9 5 12 1 6 8 10 2 4 11 3 6 8 9 1 10 12 7 0 11 0 5 4 7 2
1 7 11 9 0 2 6 6 5 0 8 3 10 8 7 12 3 9 12 4 2 4 11 1 5 10
8 4 9 0 7 3 1 3 9 6 11 6 8 2 12 10 2 12 5 5 0 1 10 7 4 11
13 4 13 4 1 2 9 8 10 7 3 12 2 0 5 6 0 5 8 6 9 12 11 10 1 7 3 11
13 0 0 6 1 4 11 3 12 9 2 10 9 2 7 8 12 5 7 6 11 4 10 1 5 3 13 8
13 10 3 6 12 1 0 8 5 6 3 11 4 9 2 9 8 11 12 2 5 7 7 1 4 10 0 13
7 4 11 8 10 1 6 0 3 10 6 0 8 2 11 5 3 1 7 13 9 13 12 9 4 2 5 12
13 5 7 6 1 12 8 2 8 0 5 7 10 6 4 11 12 1 2 10 3 13 11 3 0 9 9 4
9 2 4 3 7 4 2 7 10 5 13 6 5 12 8 11 0 8 14 11 0 6 1 9 3 13 14 1 10 12
8 14 8 7 11 7 2 12 4 5 13 6 1 3 5 0 1 4 9 0 10 2 11 12 13 6 3 14 10 9
4 9 5 1 5 10 2 11 2 9 13 10 3 13 12 8 7 1 6 8 14 0 4 12 14 11 3 7 6 0
5 10 4 3 2 4 2 3 9 13 14 6 0 11 5 13 12 8 0 9 7 8 6 11 14 1 12 10 1 7
11 1 10 8 0 12 9 1 7 4 4 12 6 8 14 5 10 5 14 0 11 3 7 9 2 2 3 13 6 13
0 8 15 6 4 1 9 8 14 13 2 11 4 6 9 14 0 2 3 5 1 15 5 10 13 12 3 7 12 7 10 11
13 3 4 13 2 12 9 1 5 1 6 7 11 9 10 0 15 14 12 15 14 8 7 3 4 5 8 11 0 2 10 6
6 1 7 9 3 1 15 7 5 14 9 14 0 8 10 0 4 12 12 13 3 6 11 4 15 2 11 5 2 13 8 10
2 0 14 7 13 13 15 7 3 8 15 5 10 12 4 5 3 14 9 6 12 10 9 11 8 6 1 1 4 11 2 0
3 13 12 4 10 13 8 0 7 11 11 6 8 1 12 5 5 9 6 10 14 3 2 9 14 4 1 15 15 7 0 2
16 12 7 14 13 5 5 4 11 0 0 9 12 15 15 9 14 2 6 3 11 8 16 10 6 13 3 1 2 8 1 7 10 4
5 5 10 4 9 15 0 11 11 1 13 15 9 0 3 1 16 6 8 7 2 6 8 2 14 14 16 4 3 12 12 13 10 7
0 6 7 4 12 16 0 3 6 1 7 12 8 13 15 9 2 11 2 15 11 10 5 13 14 5 9 14 3 8 4 16 1 10
8 0 1 2 16 11 3 2 15 4 15 5 14 9 13 7 14 9 10 12 11 12 16 6 13 6 1 5 10 0 7 8 4 3
9 16 15 13 11 2 5 6 16 3 9 4 10 14 14 12 8 11 0 6 0 15 10 7 13 5 1 12 3 4 2 1 7 8
11 15 14 3 8 12 17 15 1 0 12 6 9 0 9 13 11 14 16 2 4 5 13 16 10 7 8 5 10 4 17 3 6 7 1 2
11 14 5 7 14 0 12 4 8 12 11 13 16 16 15 6 3 1 8 3 1 5 7 17 10 2 17 13 15 9 9 4 2 0 6 10
15 13 6 12 5 4 9 2 11 2 13 16 3 9 1 16 10 11 1 12 14 17 8 0 17 6 8 10 5 0 7 4 14 7 3 15
0 9 13 15 8 11 6 5 9 16 11 7 14 7 5 15 3 12 4 16 2 14 3 0 1 10 13 1 6 10 17 2 17 8 4 12
10 13 14 10 5 7 16 8 8 7 6 3 0 2 17 17 2 1 15 16 3 4 5 0 12 9 1 12 14 11 13 9 15 6 4 11
7 14 0 13 15 6 12 1 14 16 10 15 8 11 0 9 2 3 4 18 12 17 8 13 9 6 4 11 5 1 5 16 17 3 18 10 7 2
12 9 17 2 7 12 4 15 13 0 17 9 11 3 6 4 8 5 11 16 8 1 7 0 13 15 16 10 3 14 18 2 14 1 10 6 18 5
4 0 5 14 7 8 1 0 12 15 11 2 11 5 3 9 15 17 6 8 7 10 12 3 6 16 2 18 16 13 4 14 9 17 13 18 1 10
13 13 18 9 0 17 12 17 8 0 14 16 14 6 10 6 9 15 1 15 2 4 11 5 1 3 4 3 11 2 5 16 8 7 10 7 18 12
18 11 13 6 14 9 13 14 9 18 17 11 0 1 17 2 0 6 10 3 8 4 1 5 15 7 5 2 12 15 4 8 7 16 10 12 3 16
0 17 5 6 19 0 11 1 7 18 9 14 16 2 16 13 1 4 3 17 15 7 10 2 15 9 18 13 8 14 6 12 5 10 3 8 11 19 12 4
4 3 10 12 2 7 9 11 0 16 16 7 19 2 13 3 12 10 5 18 4 15 15 0 11 19 18 13 14 1 5 17 6 9 14 8 6 17 8 1
0 17 16 11 7 19 8 5 17 16 14 1 10 6 11 7 15 10 14 13 15 4 2 4 1 9 6 3 13 18 18 0 19 3 9 12 8 5 2 12
10 15 10 0 2 14 3 19 1 18 4 14 8 2 5 17 4 11 17 12 13 16 9 3 0 13 7 5 18 6 8 9 12 1 19 16 11 7 6 15
15 2 16 4 14 0 1 5 12 18 10 12 4 14 16 11 8 7 13 15 11 3 19 10 3 9 17 6 13 19 9 1 0 18 8 2 7 5 17 6
1 12 17 7 8 8 12 20 5 10 20 16 13 3 18 15 5 4 10 9 6 14 11 6 7 15 16 19 0 1 9 18 19 2 2 3 13 4 17 0 11 14
7 17 2 12 19 9 0 11 17 4 12 0 10 11 16 14 3 20 7 15 2 9 8 18 16 19 5 3 8 14 6 18 1 13 5 1 4 15 13 10 6 20
0 18 12 4 20 7 14 5 10 16 1 13 9 15 12 0 6 19 2 5 16 10 1 17 15 11 20 3 14 2 18 3 17 11 7 8 4 8 6 19 13 9
9 18 15 0 16 7 19 4 13 20 5 10 2 2 0 12 8 6 3 15 16 14 17 7 10 3 13 6 1 20 1 17 19 11 5 4 12 14 11 8 9 18
13 6 16 11 20 3 10 8 5 7 17 15 14 0 7 6 14 17 4 15 2 12 8 1 13 18 11 10 1 9 20 16 5 19 18 2 12 19 3 9 4 0
4 5 16 11 2 1 14 9 16 6 20 21 0 13 12 13 7 8 15 11 10 18 14 3 15 5 21 18 12 17 19 9 0 19 7 4 3 20 1 8 2 10 6 17
10 6 7 0 18 1 19 5 8 12 15 2 5 4 11 20 16 17 13 14 17 1 16 9 21 21 0 3 6 3 2 7 8 13 19 20 14 15 9 11 10 4 18 12
2 20 12 21 10 4 8 11 13 3 20 1 6 21 12 13 4 17 19 16 17 15 14 9 16 9 5 10 8 6 11 18 1 5 2 18 0 0 3 7 19 14 15 7
16 0 17 8 11 6 3 18 9 16 14 20 12 12 10 1 14 1 10 21 4 19 0 2 13 3 15 17 21 9 6 18 2 20 4 11 7 19 5 8 7 5 13 15
3 4 4 10 0 3 16 14 19 8 17 9 5 9 6 12 7 13 13 1 15 0 5 20 2 7 1 17 21 11 11 18 20 6 15 16 2 12 14 19 8 10 18 21
12 11 7 8 8 10 9 18 5 6 15 12 10 0 14 3 6 22 17 15 17 21 14 16 9 4 18 13 1 11 4 20 3 19 22 1 13 7 21 5 0 20 2 2 16 19
2 20 10 17 6 0 21 10 19 4 12 8 0 7 18 15 17 18 9 4 2 14 1 5 14 6 16 22 13 11 11 15 21 3 7 19 8 9 22 20 3 16 13 1 12 5
12 11 6 16 18 15 12 11 10 9 8 15 22 5 21 18 20 0 2 19 17 8 10 5 3 14 9 22 20 3 1 21 19 6 0 16 1 13 4 14 2 13 17 4 7 7
20 5 16 4 17 7 8 15 0 10 9 3 16 13 8 12 1 14 17 11 18 11 2 7 6 1 4 20 3 5 22 22 2 6 13 10 19 15 12 14 18 9 0 19 21 21
11 1 0 5 7 15 0 12 3 9 6 15 7 13 11 20 9 17 8 4 22 4 10 5 21 18 16 14 13 10 18 12 21 17 16 2 6 22 3 14 19 1 8 19 20 2
10 10 18 6 4 1 9 6 15 7 7 11 21 13 15 21 22 16 12 20 2 18 3 17 19 14 14 0 16 5 3 4 1 9 13 11 22 20 19 8 5 0 23 17 23 2 8 12
3 3 19 13 5 10 17 18 4 16 6 2 21 4 12 7 13 8 7 10 6 2 1 15 5 21 23 22 0 11 9 16 20 11 20 23 1 14 18 8 14 19 9 17 0 15 22 12
14 7 15 20 19 7 13 0 20 2 18 1 11 21 17 12 16 10 8 3 15 2 22 23 18 16 9 1 3 13 10 19 8 11 6 4 5 22 0 17 21 23 14 4 12 9 6 5
1 12 15 21 11 21 18 6 4 22 5 23 14 19 13 8 15 7 5 0 8 13 16 4 1 6 12 11 14 18 20 17 9 23 19 3 2 17 9 0 16 7 3 20 10 22 2 10
23 9 15 10 13 17 17 21 12 18 2 20 3 8 0 16 2 12 6 20 7 19 16 0 8 9 4 6 5 13 18 14 1 19 21 3 22 15 1 4 22 10 5 7 11 14 11 23
3 21 22 5 19 7 2 24 18 19 9 2 24 14 6 0 12 0 21 18 23 15 8 11 6 4 8 17 16 20 14 16 4 7 10 11 1 9 17 3 23 10 20 5 13 22 13 1 12 15
13 6 5 22 1 17 2 21 5 0 14 24 19 21 7 19 6 23 12 14 4 9 3 22 15 9 2 16 20 7 13 12 8 23 18 0 15 10 8 24 20 16 3 1 4 11 10 18 17 11
12 6 19 0 9 14 22 2 13 20 19 9 6 3 21 20 24 0 4 24 1 5 11 15 1 21 8 5 16 16 23 18 7 11 10 17 15 12 3 22 7 10 2 23 17 8 14 4 13 18
6 22 2 18 16 19 12 0 17 14 23 4 6 17 3 10 4 22 13 9 20 19 0 9 8 1 24 2 23 14 11 5 7 16 13 10 12 8 7 3 20 21 15 5 18 21 11 1 15 24
18 12 6 22 19 19 9 24 5 14 13 2 22 8 4 16 3 9 18 8 0 10 23 10 2 20 21 5 23 20 1 11 0 17 7 7 17 12 15 3 16 15 13 24 14 4 6 21 11 1
7 14 19 5 4 17 1 22 23 24 12 1 20 6 24 7 21 10 8 11 20 3 25 13 0 2 16 21 0 6 9 11 4 18 22 2 15 5 18 8 13 12 3 14 23 10 17 9 16 15 25 19
10 4 1 13 11 24 7 12 15 20 11 0 23 23 5 7 25 25 17 8 20 24 2 22 19 9 12 16 4 6 21 9 17 6 5 15 10 0 18 8 22 2 14 16 3 19 21 18 1 3 13 14
16 22 3 2 25 21 11 1 10 12 4 15 0 2 13 11 3 14 19 1 18 12 8 23 18 22 9 16 4 0 20 9 17 24 7 10 6 8 23 25 15 7 21 20 19 5 14 13 6 5 17 24
21 20 8 16 1 18 4 0 14 5 22 3 0 23 22 1 9 4 24 7 21 2 23 15 11 12 14 25 8 12 7 15 13 18 3 19 10 2 5 10 16 24 19 13 6 20 6 9 17 11 17 25
6 24 17 18 24 22 10 11 20 16 16 3 4 21 23 25 14 1 0 1 7 2 5 13 6 4 10 21 17 14 23 11 9 9 15 25 0 19 19 12 20 22 12 13 15 2 3 8 5 18 8 7
11 16 25 6 19 5 26 17 24 6 12 4 15 18 21 7 10 5 23 3 13 8 13 23 20 8 11 12 9 22 1 14 21 2 25 10 15 9 0 2 0 26 3 24 17 22 14 4 18 16 20 19 1 7
26 0 19 3 0 20 1 25 13 3 12 6 20 11 21 13 2 11 23 15 17 15 24 23 10 8 26 5 18 9 16 18 4 9 19 10 14 7 22 17 22 4 16 8 24 2 25 5 14 12 6 21 1 7
9 25 13 14 19 17 20 2 11 5 19 23 25 21 0 16 8 15 7 16 24 24 3 15 20 10 8 4 0 12 13 22 9 4 26 18 22 2 23 18 3 6 6 12 17 26 21 10 1 11 14 7 5 1
17 4 20 23 13 0 3 26 25 16 3 2 13 10 8 12 9 5 14 2 26 25 21 23 22 17 7 14 24 1 4 15 19 16 12 5 9 22 1 20 19 7 11 6 21 15 11 18 6 8 18 0 10 24
14 12 3 17 7 2 19 11 0 21 10 24 4 6 8 8 25 4 6 23 9 1 25 15 12 9 23 10 2 26 1 0 11 7 19 13 18 3 17 13 16 26 20 20 16 15 22 22 18 14 5 24 21 5
4 15 22 10 27 14 7 0 2 17 3 6 20 18 0 16 21 4 3 11 11 12 23 5 15 22 9 17 2 1 10 18 25 14 27 19 16 23 20 21 6 25 26 24 13 1 24 26 9 13 8 19 8 7 5 12
3 17 8 9 3 9 23 15 10 25 0 6 26 21 11 12 27 1 11 13 14 2 6 1 20 7 19 24 22 14 22 25 16 17 26 5 24 27 12 13 18 4 23 20 19 4 7 15 21 8 5 16 10 2 0 18
9 11 14 21 3 12 10 4 14 1 5 18 27 9 6 0 3 19 7 12 17 26 26 25 15 11 16 24 17 18 20 8 7 19 15 1 4 13 22 23 8 25 20 16 22 2 6 0 10 5 2 24 23 21 13 27
7 23 2 26 5 24 19 17 2 18 11 7 16 5 8 26 24 21 8 14 10 16 18 9 27 1 4 22 15 25 17 4 0 0 21 3 15 12 11 23 19 27 10 13 6 22 3 14 6 13 12 9 20 1 20 25
17 4 24 21 11 22 12 13 0 1 17 23 15 4 6 2 27 14 3 16 8 13 3 5 2 6 0 9 23 14 25 26 10 18 19 26 8 11 10 20 21 18 22 20 25 9 7 12 1 7 19 16 5 27 15 24
8 27 28 24 9 9 16 22 13 20 23 25 13 21 0 26 21 8 16 24 27 18 26 23 3 7 3 25 22 15 14 6 5 7 11 4 1 20 17 19 17 12 4 14 2 1 5 18 2 28 12 0 10 19 15 11 6 10
21 9 3 23 27 4 15 22 12 2 16 26 4 13 28 16 20 6 6 3 10 1 18 5 11 0 21 7 8 25 23 17 9 15 22 14 24 2 5 10 12 17 20 1 24 7 18 0 14 26 19 13 28 25 11 8 27 19
26 10 19 20 17 10 9 19 7 15 4 27 0 15 18 2 6 2 22 6 12 25 11 9 24 26 5 11 5 21 17 7 8 4 18 14 16 24 28 1 3 28 27 14 12 8 13 13 23 3 16 23 25 21 22 0 1 20
1 0 19 11 20 17 8 3 2 18 7 18 21 5 26 9 10 6 20 2 28 8 26 19 21 17 16 14 3 14 22 12 13 6 24 9 10 22 0 27 11 13 27 7 15 4 28 1 16 23 25 23 25 12 24 15 4 5
5 9 12 7 19 25 6 24 12 6 25 3 1 16 28 2 3 14 16 4 5 26 7 8 20 19 18 22 10 27 13 28 21 17 11 26 4 18 0 20 27 24 15 10 23 11 0 21 9 22 13 14 8 1 17 15 23 2
```

Comment: If I use an rng, I could get very different results between runs.  Perhaps score based on the average of 100 runs?

Comment: @Spitemaster It is possible that a different RNG would change the score to be +1 or -1, but as scores get larger, the RNG seed matters less.  If a person posts a solution that required a very specific RNG seed, it wouldn't be reproducible, and therefore, invalid.

Comment: This seems like a nice challenge but it's a bit vague. What do you mean by "Your function must use this [32 bytes of] data". We can't use local variables? Do we have to assign that parameter that was passed to us in the function call to another value to be able to store data?

Answer (score 0):

## Lunar Arithmetic

Lunar Arithmetic (also called *dismal* arithmetic, a play on decimal) is an alternative to elemental arithmetic in which only addition and multiplication is defined, and then only for non-negative integers. For single-digit numbers, addition is defined as the maximum of the two digits, and multiplication is defined as the smaller of the two digits. For example:

```
2 + 5 = 5 + 2 = 5
2 * 5 = 5 * 2 = 2
```

To extend lunar addition to multi-digit numbers, simply consider the digits individually, counting empty digit places as zeroes as required. For example, consider `169 + 84`:

```
  1 6 9
+   8 4
  -----
  1 8 9
```

Lunar multiplication can now be dealt with in the same way as normal long multiplication, using the lunar rules for addition and multiplication. For example, consider `169 * 84`:

```
    1 6 9
*     8 4
  -------
    1 4 4    (169 * 4)
+ 1 6 8      (169 * 8)
  -------
  1 6 8 4
```

### The challenge

Write a function or program which, when given two integers, returns the result of their lunar addition and their lunar multiplication, in any order.

- The input pair may be presented as a two-element list or array.
- Input numbers may be provided in any reasonable format, including as a string, or as a list of digits.
- Output may similarly be in any reasonable format.
- The two output numbers must be separated in an unambiguous way, such as with newlines, spaces, as elements of a list or array.
- Links to online demonstrations are appreciated, but not required.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes per language wins!

In your submission, please specify the order in which the two results are presented, and your input and output formats if they are out of the ordinary.

### Test cases

**Test cases go here**

### Resources

[Original paper outlining dismal arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1130.pdf)

[Numberphile video discussing lunar arithmetic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZkGeR9CWbk)

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

---

## Sandbox business

I see this as the potential starting point for a number of Lunar arithmetic challenges, such as computing the result of a longer calculation (such as `12+345*67*8`), identification of lunar primes, lunar prime factorisation, methods of implementing subtraction and division... Of course that all depends on the response to this challenge. Any feedback on how to make this challenge better would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Posted: [FreeChat Online](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175908/56433)

Comment: You're posting to main way too fast. I recommend waiting for at least a couple of days; people have to read before giving you some feedback (comment, upvote, whatever) anyway.

Comment: okay @Bubbler I'll wait next time

Comment: After you post a challenge, please edit the post and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

## Display a rational tangle [WIP]

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

In a quest to classify mathematical knots, J. H. Conway discovered that certain simpler knotlike structures called *rational tangles* can be uniquely represented by rational numbers.

A tangle is an arrangement of two strands of rope such that each of the four ends lies at one corner of a rectangle. The four exceptional tangles are 0, 1, -1, and a special case usually referred to as 0/0 or ∞. A rational tangle is a tangle that can be obtained from the exceptional tangles by the following operations.

[image: Example of rational tangles]

An example of a rational tangle, and the tangles 0/0, 0, 1, and -1 respectively.

[image]

The rational tangle operations

Because every rational number can be obtained by addition, negation, and reciprocal, there exists some rational tangle corresponding to every rational number.

If tangle `a` and `b` have rational number values `x` and `y respectively, then the operations in the diagram result in the following values.

```
Tangle |  Value
-a          -x
1/a         1/x
a + b      x + y
a b       -x + y
a , b     -x + -y
```

## Challenge

Using the below representations of the four exceptional rational tangles, display an ASCII art rational tangle corresponding to a given rational number.

#### Exceptional rational tangles

```
\_/   \ /
 _    | |
/ \   / \
```

3x3 ASCII art representing the rational tangles 1/0 and 0

```
\ /   \ /
 \     /
/ \   / \
```

The rational tangles 1 and -1, illustrating how to display crossings

#### Displaying more complex rational tangles

Adding and rotating the above 3x3 blocks and rotation can yield any rational tangle.

- To flip a rational tangle over the line x=y, switch all instances of 1 and -1, switch all instances of 0/0 and 0, and replace all extenders (below) as appropriate.
- To rotate a rational tangle by 90 degrees in either direction, rotate the ASCII art by 90 degrees in that direction, switch all `\` and `/`, switch all instances of 0/0 and 0, and replace all extenders (below) as appropriate.
- To add two rational tangles, juxtapose them in the appropriate direction and orientation, adding extenders if dimensions do not match. Then surround the result with the following.

Pattern to surround the sum of two tangles in:

```
\ ... /
       
⋮      ⋮
       
/ ... \
```

Extenders:

```
 \        /
  |      |
 ...    ...
  |      |
   \    /

\_..._
      \

 _..._/
/
```

#### Examples

One possible representation of the tangle obtained through the equation [...]. This tangle is congruent to [...] because =.

```
 \       /
  \_   _/ 
    \ /  
     /   
  __/ \_ 
 /      \
 \      / 
  \ /\ / 
   \  \  
  / \/ \
 /      \
/        \
```

#### Input

A rational number. If you instead take input as an ordered pair (numerator,denominator) of integers, you will have `denominator >= 0`. (Denominator 0 is necessary to represent 0/0.)

#### Output

An ASCII-art representation of the rational tangle corresponding to said number, where a crossing is displayed as one of the above. Whitespace can occur anywhere. Output can contain unnecessary copies of 0, or have other variations as long as the rational tangle is obtained by operations whose corresponding arithmetic operations result in the input.

#### Further sources

A further explanation of tangles and rational tangles: (https://rationaltangle.wordpress.com/what-are-tanglesrational-tangles/)

---

TODO: Reciprocal operation, better example, reference implementation

Should continued fraction representations be acceptable?

Since this is probably a difficult challenge and answers to such are undervoted, I'm prepared to award a bounty to the shortest answer and any improvement thereon.

This is getting more unwieldy. I'm thinking of simplifying into a challenge to simply add two rational tangles.

Comment: The introduction seems to be written as a reminder to someone who already knows the topic and needs a refresher. To someone who's never heard of rational tangles before, it throws up a lot more questions than answers. What's 0/0 (other than NaN)? What's ramification? What (other than a+b, which is fairly straightforward) is the diagram supposed to show? The intro says that the ends of the rope must be in the corners of a square: should that say *rectangle*? In the ASCII art, how do extenders cross?

Comment: 1. Which part of the diagram corresponds to reciprocal? Does the left-hand part somehow show both negation and reciprocal at the same time? 2. Having looked at your additional reading link, the challenge turns out to be much simpler than the question made it seem. The paragraph starting "*The two simplest tangles*" and the subsequent one seem to be all that's needed. Perhaps you could use a simple challenge as an introduction and then have a follow-up which asks for an equality test?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Reciprocal is flipping over some axis, I forget which one. 2. Will do when I have time. I probably won't end up posting this for another month.

Answer (score 0):

## Octonion multiplication [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [complex-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)

### Background

**[Octonion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion)** is a further extension to the quaternion number system. An octonion can be written as

$$ x = x_0 e_0 + x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 + x_3 e_3 + x_4 e_4 + x_5 e_5 + x_6 e_6 + x_7 e_7 $$

where \$ x_i \$ are real numbers and \$ e_i \$ are the eight *unit octonions*.

Octonion multiplication has the following properties:

- It is not commutative, i.e. \$ xy \ne yx \$.
- It is not associative, i.e. \$ x(yz) \ne (xy)z \$.
- But, luckily, multiplication is distributive over addition, i.e. \$ x(y+z) = xy + xz \$ and \$ (x+y)z = xz + yz\$.

The multiplication rule for unit octonions is presented below:

(will add a table from Wikipedia)

The unit octonions have several properties:

- \$ e_0 \$ behaves like a real number 1.
- \$ e_i^2 = -1 \$ and \$ e_i e_j = -e_j e_i \$ for \$ 1 \le i,j \le 7, i \ne j \$.

### Task

Multiply two octonion numbers.

### Input & output

You can accept and output an octonion as any kind of consistent structure consisting of eight real numbers (four complex numbers or two quaternions or a mixture of types is also fine).

### Test cases

Coming soon.

### Scoring & winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest program or function in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: \$1e_0+2e_1+3e_2+4e_3+5e_4+6e_5+7e_6+8e_7\$ is written in NARS2000 as `1i2j3k4l5ij6jk7kl8`. ;-)

Comment: Somehow, I think NARS APL will win this one…

Answer (score 0):

## Make numbers inflate to full width! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

> **Related: [Full Width Text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75979/full-width-text)**
>
> That is a challenge that changes ALL characters into full width -- BY ADDING A SPACE AFTER EACH CHARACTER. However, in this challenge only numbers are transformed, and are transform to the **[REAL FULL WIDTH FORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)**

.

> This is a short and simple challenge, so I will keep the description short.

### Challenge

Write a program / function that accepts an ASCII string as input and outputs a UTF string with each number `0123456789` converted to its corresponding full width form `０１２３４５６７８９`. The range of these full width numbers is `U+FF10 - U+FF19`.

You may output using the following format (As an example `This is 1 apple` is used):

- A UTF-8 string (showing exactly `This is １ apple` in STDOUT)
- The same string as above but displayed in a non-UTF-8 encoding (eg. showing `This is ï¼‘ apple` in Windows-1252 codepage). In this case you must state the codepage of the output
- A single list of UTF-8 bytes as integers that represents the transformed string (showing `ord("T"),...,ord(" "),239,188,145,ord(" "),...,ord("e")` with arbitrary delimiter)

You cannot mix integer output and character output, that is, you cannot literally change `This is 1 apple` to `This is [239,188,145] apple`. You cannot output a nested list if a list is outputted either.

### Sample I/O

- Sample 1:

  ```
  Input:  0123456789
  Output: (Format 1) ０１２３４５６７８９
          (Format 2) ∩╝É∩╝æ∩╝Æ∩╝ô∩╝ö∩╝ò∩╝û∩╝ù∩╝ÿ∩╝Ö [CP437]
          (Format 3) 239,188,144,239,188,145,239,188,146,239,188,147,239,188,148,239,188,149,239,188,150,239,188,151,239,188,152,239,188,153
  ```
- Sample 2:

  ```
  Input:  This is 1 apple
  Output: (Format 1) This is １ apple
          (Format 2) This is ï¼‘ apple [Windows-1252]
          (Format 3) 0x54 0x68 0x69 0x73 0x20 0x69 0x73 0x20 0xef 0xbc 0x91 0x20 0x61 0x70 0x70 0x6c 0x65
  ```

### Footnote

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer for each language wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden by default.

P.S. I would like to see both practical and esoteric language submissions. Specifically the last two output formats are especially allowed for esoteric languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Help Runbee manage the pollen! [better title needed?]

[The  <s>arsonist</s>  friendly bee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164484/59487), Runbee, just finished picking up the pollen from the flower garden and now she wants to store it safely in her hive. Each pollen type is labeled with a digit (from **1** to **9**). Runbee's "collection" is stored in a row of adjacent honeycomb cells, containing one grain each. For instance, this row could look like this:

```
1 3 2 2 4 4 4 5 3 3 3 7 8 9 9 5
```

But hmm, Runbee doesn't like this order... Because she's tired after flying all day, she can now only move a run of identical adjacent pollen grains to another position in the row to make it seem more organised. Her goal is to have as many identical pollen types one after another after the reordering.

#### Task

Given a sequence **S** of digits ranging from **1** to **9**, one shall:

- Split **S** into (the longest possible) runs of consecutive adjacent elements. Then, one of the chunks should be moved to another position in **S**.
- The resulting sequence **S'** should be chopped again into (the longest possible) runs of consecutive adjacent elements. Your goal is to search for the sequence **S'** which contains the most equal consecutive elements.
- You can either output all such sequences **S'** (deduplicated or not) or just one of them.

For the example above, the possible ways to generate optimal orderings are (where `(...)` represent the point of removal and `[...]` the point of addition):

```
1 (3) 2 2 4 4 4 5 [3] 3 3 3 7 8 9 9 5     | 1 2 2 4 4 4 5 3 3 3 3 7 8 9 9 5 
1 (3) 2 2 4 4 4 5 3 3 3 [3] 7 8 9 9 5     | 1 2 2 4 4 4 5 3 3 3 3 7 8 9 9 5
1 3 [3 3 3] 2 2 4 4 4 5 (3 3 3) 7 8 9 9 5 | 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 4 4 4 5 7 8 9 9 5
1 [3 3 3] 3 2 2 4 4 4 5 (3 3 3) 7 8 9 9 5 | 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 4 4 4 5 7 8 9 9 5
```

#### Rules

... To be written ..

#### Test cases

... To be added ..

Comment: Suggested testcase: `1 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 1`

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176992)

Comment: Note. Because TSP (decision version) is NP and maximum independent set is NP-hard, it's possible to have polynomial-time complexity; however given how unrelated those two problems appear to be, the actual transformation would be nontrivial and may be interesting to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling a survey. You don't like filling such thing, so you decide to automatically fill some random thing.

However, there may be some duplicated question, and some may be inverted. To simplify the question, we define:

1. Adding or removing word "not" or "no" inverts the sentence;
2. Adding or removing "un" at the beginning of a word inverts the sentence;
3. Adding or removing "n't" at the end of a word inverts the sentence;
4. Adding or removing word "any", "a" or "an" keeps (doesn't invert) the sentence;

Invertion can go through sentences even if they are not asked. E.g. "Do you own a car?" is twice inverted to "Don't you own no car?", so they should have same answer, no matter what sentences left are mentioned.

Input: A list of string, each of which is a sentence.

Output: A list of 2-possible-value, where inverted sentences are answered different and same sentences are answered same.

Sample Input:

```
Are you rich?
Are you unrich?
Are you poor?
Are you rich?
Are you not rich?
```

Possible sample outputs (assuming 0 and 1 as possible outputs)

```
1,0,0,1,0
1,0,1,1,0
0,1,0,0,1
0,1,1,0,1
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Decided to not have [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) to try to have more creative solution

Comment: I would rather have this challenge something closer to just "identify duplicate questions" rather than "create a possible set of answers such that you answer duplicate questions with appropriate inversion". Something like "Given two sentences, output one of 3 distinct values to indicate whether they are "duplicate", "inverted", or "unrelated"". If you insist on keeping the output as possible answers, then your "output" line needs to say so rather than just "a list"

Comment: @KamilDrakari If no [tag:random] requirement, false relation or something else may exist. Considered

Comment: @KamilDrakari That is a good option, because it is a large part of the challenge, and the other part is likely to be implemented using brute force ⇒ very slow, not testable.

Comment: @user202729 Nope, they'll count `no`s, `un`s and `n't`s and mod2

Answer (score 0):

## Separate the syllables - in Finnish

Given a Finnish word as a string, separate each syllable.

### Wait, what?

In Finnish, syllables are very important for many different things in the grammar - often, the first place a foreigner starts with the language is with the syllable structure.
Your job, as a prospective learner, is to decompose the given word into its syllables. To do this, your program or function must return a string in which the syllables have been separated by a single `|` or `-`.

### But how?

Given any word, you can split the syllables apart by following five simple rules. In the below mapping, V indicates a *vowel* (aeiouyäö), a *diphthong* or a *long vowel* (see below) and C indicates a *consonant* (bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz). '-' indicates where the word should be split. Patterns are "greedy", so the longest matching pattern is the one that should be applied.

> VV -> V-V
>
> VC -> VC
>
> VCV -> V-CV
>
> VCCV -> VC-CV
>
> VCCCV -> VCC-CV

### What the &@?! are diphtongs?

Because Finnish is [a complex language](https://www.basedonblog.com/2015/12/random-facts-about-finland.html), we can't just let foreigners get off that easy with learning the basics! So, we came up with *diphtongs* - pairs of *vowels* that are considered a single *vowel* when determining syllables. The list of the ones important to this challenge is as follows (in an arbitrary order):

> ai, ei, oi, ui, yi, äi, öi, ey, iy, äy, öy, au, eu, ou, iu, ie, uo, yö

Furthermore, we have *long vowels* - these also count as a single vowel, and are simply the vowel repeated twice:

> aa, ee, ii, oo, uu, yy, ää, öö

### What else?

You should note that:

- [Default loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- [Default I/O is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- You may take input and produce output in any string encoding that contains at least the following characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö-|` and/or their upper-case equivalents.
- The encoding must be the same for input and for output.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer wins.

### Give me the solutions!

Examples are given as `input -> output` with syllable boundaries indicated by a `-`.

```
perkele -> per-ke-le
sauna -> sau-na
koskenkorva -> kos-ken-kor-va
nopea -> no-pe-a
maa -> maa
suomenkieli -> suo-men-kie-li
esimerkki -> e-si-merk-ki
itsenäisyyspäivä -> it-se-näi-syys-päi-vä
koodigolffi -> koo-di-golf-fi
toritapaaminen -> to-ri-ta-paa-mi-nen
```

### Finally...

Happy golfing!

Comment: I don't understand how to use the patterns. What is the point of the VC pattern if it does not have any split?

Comment: @feersum It's just there to indicate that any trailing consonants are considered part of the same syllable as the preceding vowel (i.e. the last example).

Answer (score 0):

## Validate a simple bell-ringing method

A simple bell-ringing method on `n` bells has the following characteristics.

1. Each row exchanges at least one pair of adjacent bells. Any given bell can only take part in one exchange per row.
2. The notation for a row lists those bells that are not exchanged. Each row is separated with a `.`. However, rows that exchange all bells are notated with an `X` and do not use `.` separators, so that `.16..16.` would actually be notated `X16X16X`.
3. The first `n-1` rows always exchange bell 1 with the next bell so that it becomes last.
4. The `n`th row, also known has the half lead, does not exchange bell 1.
5. The next `n-1` rows are the same as the first `n-1` rows but in reverse order. This brings bell 1 back to its original position.
6. The `2n`th row, also known as the lead end, also does not exchange bell 1.
7. Up to three different lead ends may be used, being named "Plain", "Bob" and "Single".
8. After the lead end, the `2n-1` rows are rung again, possibly with a different lead end, and this repeats according to a predetermined pattern known as a touch.
9. The method starts and finishes with the bells in ascending order.

The following parts are intended to be submitted as separate questions.

### Part 1

Given any number of rows in bell-ringing notation, return a truthy or falsy value depending on whether they represent a valid permutation.

### Part 2

Given any number of rows in bell-ringing notation, convert them to permutations and output them in the most convenient format for input into subsequent parts.

### Part 3

Given a list of permutations corresponding to the first `n` rows of a method, append the first `n-1` rows in reverse order, and then output the result of combining the permutations.

### Part 4

Given the permutation from part 3, and up to three different lead end permutations as output by part 2, and a string representing which the order in which the lead ends are to be used, calculate the permutations before and after each lead end, ensuring that they are all different, and that the last permutation is that the identity permutation.

Example:

```
Main rows: 5.1.5.1.5
Plain lead: 125
Bob: 145
Touch: PBPPBPBPPB
```

`5.1.5.1.5` means that the permutations are `(12)(34)` and `(23)(45)` repeated, so the permutation before the first lead end in this case turns out to be just `(23)(45)` again. The plain lead is `(34)` and the bob is `(23)`. The relevant permutations for the touch are as follows:

```
(23)(45)
(2453)
(25)
(235)
(245)
(2345)
(35)
(345)
(243)
(34)
(2354)
(2453)
(25)(34)
(2435)
(2534)
(253)
(354)
(45)
(23)
```

then finishing with the identity permutation as desired.

Comment: I have to say, I am entirely confused by this and haven't the slightest idea what any of it means to the point that I can barely even identify what things confuse me. However, I can at least ask one thing: Rule 3 states "exchange bell 1 with the next bell so that it becomes last". How does "exchange bell 1 with the next bell" result in "it becomes last"? If I have 3 bells I would expect the result to be `213`. Are you using a different definition of "exchange" than me?

Comment: @KamilDrakari There are `n-1` rows, which is exactly the minimum number needed to get bell 1 into last place, as long as each row moves bell 1 a further step each time.

Comment: In point 2 should `.16..16.` say `.16.16.`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, `.16..16.` is a list of five strings, three of which are empty.

Answer (score 0):

## Buddhabrot (speed edition)

Your goal is to generate an image like this one:

[image: Buddhabrot]
(Sandbox: this image will be replaced by a valid solution image for the challenge)

This is a render of a 2D histogram called Buddhabrot. The algorithm for generating it is very simple. If you have heard of (or written a program to generate) the Mandelbrot Set, this will feel familiar. The algorithm goes as follows:

1. Generate a random complex number \$z_0\$
2. Iteratively perform the calculation \$z_{i+1}=z_i^2+z_0\$. Do this \$N\$ times
3. Check if the absolute value of the number \$z_N\$ is larger than 3
4. If it is, calculate all the numbers \$z_i, 0 \leq i\leq N\$ again and map them to pixels.
5. For each pixel that is mapped to, add \$1\$ to the counter for that pixel
6. Repeat the 4 steps above a few million (or billion/trillion) times.

Since this algorithm depends on random sampling rather than just a single calculation for each pixel, it is not as easy to parallelize on a GPU. However, a GPU will still perform better than a CPU for this task. Since it is random, it is also dependent on having a large number of iterations to generate a smooth image. With a low number of iterations, the output image will be grainy.

To participate in this challenge, write a full program which creates a render of the Buddhabrot. For this challenge, the maximum iteration number is set to 100. That means that for every random complex \$z_0\$, you must write to the counter array if \$|z_{100}| > 3\$. Note that if \$|z_i| > 3\$ for some \$i < 100\$, then you can quit the calculation, since you know that \$|z_{100}| > 3\$.

If you want some help to get you started, I recently made an attempt to optimize this problem. You can [read about my journey](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205592/speeding-up-buddhabrot-calculation-in-pycuda) if you want.

### Generating the image

A basic algorithm for rendering a Buddhabrot image is described above. To make it efficient, I would suggest that you use an `unsigned int*` to hold all the counters for the pixels. When running the program, you calculate which pixel should have its counter increased, then you add 1 to that index in the counter array. When you are done with the random number generation, you take your array of counters, divide every element by the array's maximum value. Then all values in the array will be in the range \$[0,1]\$. You can then use that value as the grayscale color of the corresponding pixel.

### Specification

1. The output image must be exactly 1024x1024 pixels
2. The maximum iteration number is 100
3. The complex numbers must be sampled from the rectangle in the complex plane given by \$-2.5 < Re(z_0) < 1.5, -2 < Im(z_0) < 2\$ (Sandbox: these limits are subject to change). The sampling does not have to be uniform (you might discard points which you know are not important). However, it does need to result in a picture which is visually similar to the one in the post.
4. The output image must be a visualization of the area in the complex plane given by \$-2 < Re(z) < 2, -2 < Im(z) < 2\$ (Sandbox: these limits might change slightly)
5. You have 20 minutes to perform the sampling and generate the image. I will assist with tweaking to maximize your score.
6. You are free to use CUDA or OpenCL to generate the image. For any other methods of implementation, please include instructions on how yo get the environment ready.

### Scoring

To ensure that we have an objective criteria for scoring, your score will be the total sum of all pixel counters. Since the Buddhabrot is a 2D histogram in its essence, this can be seen as the total number of samples. To be specific, you calculate your score before dividing by the maximum value and generating the image. The highest score wins. Note that if your approach is similar to mine, the theoretical maximum score is limited by the memory bandwidth. The bandwidth of my GPU is 484GB/s, and since each counter is 4 bytes, you can get 121 billion iterations per second. However, there might be more effective ways to save the samples using the CUDA caches, which could lead to higher performance than that. (Sandbox: I'm not 100% sure if my maximum speed calculation is valid)

Since I already have a working example for this problem, I have decided to add a further incentive. If your solution is 2x faster than my implementation, I'll reward 50 reputation once one month has passed from posting the question. If it is 5x faster, the reward goes up to 100 rep. If it is more than 10x faster, I'll award 150 rep. If you somehow manage to make your solution 30x faster, I'll throw in 200 rep. If multiple answers are eligible for the bonus, only the fastest one will be rewarded. If no answer is eligible for the bounty once one month has passed, the bounty will be rewarded to the first one who claims it. However, you can only claim one bounty, so if you have made your solution 5x faster but want to claim the 10x bounty, I will give you time to optimize your solution to reach the next bounty.

### Testing machine

- Intel 5820K 6-core 12-thread CPU running at 4.4GHz
- 16GB DDR4 RAM
- NVIDIA GTX 1080Ti (11 GB GDDR5X, 3584 CUDA cores)
- CUDA 9.0 (I'll add information about C++ version and other relevant info)
- Windows 8.1 (sorry)

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[complex-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)[fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

### For the sandbox

- Right now there are a few things that need to be clarified in the description.
- I will also update the post with an image that is 1024x1024 pixels. Is the question clear?
- Do I need to clarify anything besides the information that's left out right now?
- Is it okay to add reputation rewards from the start to attract answers?
- Are GPU challenges welcome? A short discussion about hardware was had in the chat, and I'm aware that not everyone has a NVIDIA GPU. That's why I made sure that there are OpenCL implementations of this problem.
- I say that the sampling should be uniform, but there have been some optimized solutions using importance sampling for this specific problem, should I allow that?

Comment: Step 6 is "repeat the 4 steps above". Does that mean "repeat steps 2-5", or is it a mistake and should be "5 steps"?

Comment: Two parts of the challenge leave me scratching my head when combined. When describing the formula you say that "if |zi|>3 for some i<100, then you can quit the calculation, since you know that |z100|>3." which seems to imply that |zi+1|>|zi| However, in the specification you assert that the range of possible values for z0 should be identical to the range of values displayed. Either this means some samples map to pixels off-screen or... I guess I could be misunderstanding something?

Comment: @KamilDrakari I'll address all of these points more thoroughly later today. Yes, it should say repeat the 5 steps. As for the scoring, it is random, but since a good program will perform >10^10 iterations per second, the standard deviation will be very low. To maximize your score, you want to perform steps 1-5 as many times as possible within the time limit. And yes, samples could map to pixels off-screen. Those samples do not count towards your score. It is not always true that |z_i+1|>|z_i|, but if the absolute value goes above 2, it will start growing towards infinity.

Comment: Ah, I think to resolve my confusion about the scoring method you should add somewhere "Highest score wins" or "higher scores are better".

Comment: "*The sampling must not be uniform*". In that case, you need to specify what it must be.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm sorry, I meant "the sampling does not have to be uniform". I have seen some work with importance sampling, but I have not implemented that myself.

Answer (score 0):

**Where am I?**

Given an input folder structure (i.e. a tree data structure with named nodes), and a pointer to a directory (a specific node) within that tree structure, the program should output the full path to the directory the pointer is pointing at (in linux format, so `/var/log` for example), without ever inspecting the name of the current node or its ancestors; only its descendants.

The rules of the challenge are the equivalent of:

> "you can `cd` and `ls` but not `pwd`" if this was being run on a live linux files system

but I feel I should expand on that a bit regarding how it works for a tree:

- The method starts with the pointer, and it can `ls` to see what is contained within this directory (i.e. view the immediate child nodes in the tree structure, but not its own name)
- the method can also `cd dirname` into any directory (i.e. move the pointer to any immediate child in the tree from the current node), and `cd ..` to go to a previous directory (i.e. move the pointer to the immediate previous child in the tree)

  - `cd ..` leaves you in the same directory (node), if there is no parent
  - `cd invalidDirName`leaves you in the same directory (node), if there is no immediate child with that name
- Any directory can contain any number of other directories, or none.
- You are forbidden to do the equivalent of `cd /`

**Inputs**

A tree-structure representing a file system and a pointer to a node in that tree

*Assumptions*
 1. There are no duplicate folder names in the same parent folder (so `ls` can't return `folder`, `folder`; for example) - but there may be other folders with the same name elsewhere in the tree structure; in which case it doesn't matter which your program outputs (as it has no way of knowing which is correct)
 2. ...Therefore, it may not be possible to determine which folder you started in - in which case a best-guess is fine (see examples 3, 4)
 3. Symlinks and cyclical trees are not a part of this challenge - it will always be a simple parent-child tree structure - so you are always guaranteed to find the root by doing `cd ..` enough times.

**Output**

The path that the pointer was pointing at, as a string or char array (or equivalent for your language).

**Scoring**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) scoring is used, so shortest bytes wins.

**Example 1**

*input map:* `/var/ftp/in, /var/ftp/out/child, /var/etc/test/child/etc, /var/etc/test/c2/etc2, /var/etc/test/c3`

*input pointer points at:* `c2`

*sample working:*

1. `ls` -> "etc2"
2. `cd ..`, `ls` -> "child","c2", "c3" - three options, need to find which is correct
3. `cd child`, `ls` -> "etc2" - this doesn't match 1, so go back
4. `cd ..`, `cd c2`, `ls` -> "etc2" - this is correct, so I know my path ends with "/c2"
5. `cd ..`, `cd ..`, `ls` -> "test" - only one folder, so I know my path ends with "/test/c2"
6. `cd ..`, `ls` -> "ftp", "etc" - two options, need to find which is correct
7. `cd ftp`, `ls` -> "in", "out" - incorrect, so go back
8. `cd ..` -> there was only two options, so "etc" must be correct. my path ends with "/etc/test/c2"
9. `cd ..`, `ls` -> "var" - only one folder, so path ends with "/var/etc/test/c2"
10. `cd ..`, `ls` -> "var" - same option, so assume we're at root.
11. Output "/var/etc/test/c2"

**Example 2**

*input map:* /app/data/dir/in

*input pointer points at:* /app/data

*Output:* "/app/data"

**Example 3**

*input map:* /var, /app, /test

*input pointer points at:* /app

*Output:* "/var", "/app" or "/test" are all valid outputs.

Note that there is no way for the program to differentiate between the three folders; and so any of the three are a valid answer for the purposes of this application.

**Example 4**

*input map:* /var/etc/test, /app/etc/two

*input pointer points at:* /app/etc

*Output:* "/app/etc"

**Questions**

1. Does the spec make sense?

Comment: Nice idea for a challenge, but: I would remove the free `cd` and `ls` helpers for it only creates problems, you can (partially) solve the issue of using system built-ins by just allowing the directory-structure as input and not a directory-node (there will still be one or two solutions like `eval mkdir -p $1;eval $2;pwd`) but they are not really interesting and need to create the directories which is a penalty). I would also remove the explanations of examples 2-4, one suffices and more makes the post hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I think I'll remove the cd/ls stuff and the file system input, like you suggest.
What would you recommend for the examples 2-4 then - just show the input and output? Or just show the working but not the text explanations? Should I include the result of "ls" each time also in that case?

Comment: Just input and output should suffice imo. Maybe you want to exchange 1 and 2 such that there is the more thorough explanation of 2 and 1 just i/o.

Comment: done :) Thanks for your input. How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

## Prime Steganography

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [steganography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime)

---

Alice and Bob have devised a steganography encryption method where they encode the letters of their message (the "secret message") into the letters in the prime positions of the larger message  (the "carrier message"). Your job is to create a program which takes a secret message as input and outputs a carrier message that hides the secret message in the letters in the prime positions.

### Requirements

- Only letter characters in the carrier message count toward positions.
- The secret message is not case sensitive and non-letters do not need to be encoded in any way.
- The carrier message must contain only words that can be found in [this list of English words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words). The carrier message does not need to make sense.
- The carrier message can contain punctuation (any of `.,?!"':;-`), whitespace, and letter characters only.
- The carrier message cannot hide a message that is longer than the secret message. If it ends on a prime after the last one needed, it is invalid. For instance, if the carrier message is 38 letters long and the secret message is only 11 letters long, the carrier would encode an extra letter and therefore is invalid. (*Sandbox: help me phrase this better*)

### Examples

Input: 'Hello world'

Possible Output:

> Ah! Eels live! Oh wall! Oars will board.

Lining up all the letters, you get these positions

```
 A  h  E  e  l  s  l  i  v  e  O  h  w  a  l  l  O  a  r  s  w  i  l  l  b  o  a  r  d
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

All the letters in the prime positions would be extracted. `h` at 2, `E` at 3, `l` at 5, `l` at 7, `O` at 11, `w` at 13, `O` at 17, `r` at 19, `l` at 23, and `d` at 29. Thus the full message is `hEllOwOrld`, but case doesn't matter.

### Rules

- Standard rules and loopholes apply.
- You can read in the word list using any method you would like, or not at all. Other word lists may be used and will not count toward byte count, but every word in your output must appear somewhere in the [previously mentioned word list](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words).
- You may assume that the secret message only includes letters, whitespace, and punctuation.
- Your program does not need to be deterministic, but does need to always output a valid carrier message which correctly encodes the secret message.
- You may assume that the secret message is possible to encode with English words from the list. (Even though it may not be for one reason or another)

---

#### Sandbox note

I'm thinking this might make for an interesting popularity contest. The objective criteria is validity of the carrier message. The subjective criteria is how interesting/entertaining/convincing the messages that it outputs are.

Comment: Considering that only the letters of the secret message are encoded anyway, I think it would make more sense to only provide the letters of a secret message without punctuation.

Comment: I'd reccomend giving the list of words as input rather than a defined word list. This makes it much easier to test

Comment: @JoKing That would be covered by "You can read in the word list using any method you would like, or not at all. *Other word lists may be used* and will not count toward byte count, but every word in your output must appear somewhere in the previously mentioned word list." It's a pretty massive list of words, so any subset of it will do for testing.

Answer (score 0):

## Stego-nography: Hide A Stegosaurus with Steganography!

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [steganography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

**This doesn't work as a cops and robbers challenge. Leaving for possible inspiration.**

Making something that converts an image with a live dinosaur into one with a dead dinosaur would be a clone of [Hiding information in Cats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25443/hiding-information-in-cats).

---

## Cops

Devise a method for hiding this ASCII stegosaurus in an image.

```
                         .       .
                        / `.   .' "
                .---.  <    > <    >  .---.
                |    \  \ - ~ ~ - /  /    |
    _____          ..-~             ~-..-~
   |     |   \~~~\.'                    `./~~~/
  ---------   \__/                        \__/
 .'  O    \     /               /       \  "
(_____,    `._.'               |         }  \/~~~/
 `----.          /       }     |        /    \__/
       `-.      |       /      |       /      `. ,~~|
           ~-.__|      /_ - ~ ^|      /- _      `..-'
                |     /        |     /     ~-.     `-. _  _  _
                |_____|        |_____|         ~ - . _ _ _ _ _>
```

Source: [custom 'cow' for cowsay](https://github.com/piuccio/cowsay/blob/master/cows/stegosaurus.cow)

Create an encoder and a decoder. Post the decoder and two versions of three different images, each pair with and without the encoded stegosaurus. Include hashes for each of the six images.

### Rules and Scoring

- The decoder must be able to decode any arbitrary ASCII text of at least the same size as the stegosaurus (either 677 characters or 14x63 characters if you assume the text is right-padded. Be consistent).

  - Only the part of the encoded message that actually includes the stegosaurus matters; extra bytes in the message can be ignored by the user or decoder, but must be either before/after the 677 characters or outside the 14x63 bounding rectangle, depending on how you encode it. (*Sandbox: this phrasing is awkward*)
  - In short, it must be possible for the robbers to kill your dinosaur (link to robber thread goes here) by replacing your stegosaurus with a dead one.
- You may not use asymmetric encryption in your solution. (For example, encrypting the stegosaurus with your private key before hiding it and then putting the public key in the decoder)
- You can use any lossless image format of your choice.
- You do not need to post the source code of your decoder. Precompiled Windows or Linux binaries are allowed, but must be packaged with all of their dependencies and be able to be run without any installation. Obfuscation and minification are allowed for interpreted languages and likewise should prepackage all third-party dependencies.
- You may not host your decoder on a webservice. The reason why is that it enables you to use symmetric encryption with no way to derive the key.
- As an objective criteria for the encoded images to be not easily distinguishable, the maximum absolute pixel difference between the images should be less than 4/255 for each color component in the entire image.

If at least one of your dinosaurs survives after one week, your dinosaurs are safe and you earn 10 points (after which point you can explain your algorithm). If your dinosaurs are all killed within a week, you score 1 point for each 24 hour period they survived.

The cop with the most points wins.

---

## Robbers

You're a dinosaur hunter. The cops have hidden stegosauruses in three images. It's your job to find the stegos and kill them. You are to change the message hidden in each image from the original stegosaurus to this dead one:

```
                         .       .
                        / `.   .' "
                .---.  <    > <    >  .---.
                |    \  \ - ~ ~ - /  /    |
                   ..-~             ~-..-~
             \~~~\.'                    `./~~~/
              \__/                        \__/
                /               /       \  "
    _____     .'               |         }  \/~~~/
   |     |  .'   /       }     |        /    \__/
  --------''    |       /      |       /      `. ,~~|
 .'  X        __|      /_ - ~ ^|      /- _      `..-'
(_____     _-~  |     /        |     /     ~-.     `-. _  _  _
 `__U___--~     |_____|        |_____|         ~ - . _ _ _ _ _>
```

Cracking a cop submission requires that you kill all of its hidden dinosaurs. You earn a point for each submission you crack. Note that the cop can encode garbage or null data around the dinosaur (either by bounding box or before/after the 677 characters), but you do not need to leave this data untouched.

The robber with the most cracked submissions wins.

---

## Sandbox

Does this work as a cops-and-robbers challenge? Any problematic loopholes or ways to abuse this?

Comment: It's possible you simply considered this implied, but I would recommend indicating a timeframe after which a cop's answer is "safe", and requiring that safe answers post their encoder to prove that it can indeed hide arbitrary images. Requiring the decoder from the start seems best so that robbers can validate potential cracks. Also, each portion of the challenge needs some kind of scoring method.

Comment: @KamilDrakari: It will probably be a week. I just wanted to test the waters on the idea first since cops and robbers challenges are hard to make.

Comment: I'm really not sure if the stenography really adds much to the challenge.  Stenography is all about hiding the fact that secrets are being transferred in the first place.  Here, though, there's no reason to make the image look "normal", and so it becomes a "implement your own asymmetric crypto algorithm"

Comment: If "implement your own asymmetric crypto algorithm" is what you want, then I don't think this should be posted.  Banning crypto is fine if it is closing a loop hole, but here it's literally "Do crypto without using crypto".  The line will be too hard to define IMO.

Comment: @NathanMerrill: I'm definitely banning crypto to close a loophole because the challenge becomes trivial to make uncrackable with public key encryption. Symmetric crypto would be fine because you'd be able to reverse-engineer the decoder to derive a key. I suppose a possibility for better patching the loophole would be to require lossless images and require that changing a bit in the uncompressed pixel data changes at most one character in the output. That also effectively bans most hard-to-crack crypto.

Comment: Hmm... Looking over the typical cops-and-robbers challenges, none of them are related to crypto... and I can see why. I like the general concept though. I think it's fun and whimsical and I think I can convert it into one or two code challenges (code-golf, code-challenge, and popularity-contest might all work)

Answer (score 0):

## A Golden March

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)[fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

> Draw a circle whose circumference is the golden mean. Choose a point and label it 1, then move clockwise around the circle in steps of arc length 1, labeling the points 2, 3, and so on. At each step, the difference between each pair of adjacent numbers on the circle is a Fibonacci number.

from [Futility Closet](https://www.futilitycloset.com/2013/12/04/a-golden-march/).

#### Challenge

Given some natural number \$ n \geq 1 \$, determine the first \$n\$ points as described above. Then determine *all* differences between pairs of adjecent numbers and return them as a list.

#### Details

- The list should contain all the differences in the order in which they appear.
- It should start with the difference between \$1\$ and one of its adjecent neighbours. Then you need to continue recording the differences in the direction you started with.

#### Examples

to be determined.

Answer (score 0):

## Is it a D?

Given an image, check if it's a letter `D`.

Here `D` is defined as:

Let pixels labeled \$(x,y)\$ where larger \$x\$ mean at right and larger \$y\$ mean more up. If there exist \$x_0, x_1, f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3\$ such that:

- \$ (f \rightarrow (x\rightarrow f(x+1)-f(x)))^n (f_i) (x) >0\$ for \$n>0, 0\leq i<4\$
- \$ x_0<x_1\$
- Pixel \$(x,y)\$ is true iff \$y>f_0(x) \text{ and } y<-f_1(x) \text{ and } (y>-f_2(x) \text{ or } y<f_3(x) \text{ or } x_0\leq x<x_1)\$
- There should be a hole, i.e. a false pixel that can't reach border without acrossing a true pixel

Shortest code win. Don't mind if *D* doesn't follow the rule or a symbol which follows the rule doesn't look like a `D` at all

TODO: add test cases

Comment: A couple of examples would help here. Also, if I've understood the conditions correctly, I think you mean \$y>-f_2(x)\$.

Comment: Also, those are some fast-growing \$f_i\$. Your font must have really, really tall D's.

Answer (score 0):

## Prime number construction game

Tags: code-golf

Inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048245/prime-number-construction-game), here is *A "single player" version of the prime number construction game*.

#### The game:

1. Start with a digit between 1 and 9.
2. Add a digit to the end, such that the resulting number is a prime number.
3. Repeat from step 2 until there are no more possible prime numbers.

#### The challenge:

Write a function (or required functions) that returns the sum of the lengths of the largest prime numbers you can get starting with each digit, following the game rules above.

#### The score:

Scoring will have two components:

1. The length of the code, in bytes (it's code-golf, after all), and
2. The sum of the length of the largest primes obtained, starting with each digit.

The total score will be the length of the code (1) minus the sum of the length of the largest primes obtained (2).

The lowest score wins.

#### Example:

Here's a code sample using R (verbose and non golfed):

```
isprime <- function(x) {
  for(i in 2:sqrt(x))
    if(x %% i == 0)
      return(FALSE)
  return(TRUE)
}

next_prime <- function(x) {
  for(i in sample(c(1,3,7,9))) {
    y <- strtoi(paste(c(x,i), collapse=''))
    if(isprime(y))
      return(y)
  }
  return(NULL)
}

longest_primes <- function(x) {
  primes <- 1:9
  for(d in 1:9) {
    y <- d
    while(!is.null(y)) {
      primes[d] <- y
      y <- next_prime(y)
    }
  }
  return(sum(nchar(primes)))
}
```

Here's a sample run of the code above:

```
 Digit | Largest prime obtained | Length
 ------+------------------------+-------
   1   | 19139                  | 5
   2   | 29399999               | 8 
   3   | 3797                   | 4
   4   | 4799                   | 4
   5   | 53                     | 2
   6   | 6173                   | 4
   7   | 719333                 | 6
   8   | 89                     | 2
   9   | 977                    | 3
 ------+------------------------+-------
 Total |                        | 38
```

Assuming the byte count of my code is 469, my final score is 469-38=**431**.

#### Posting your solution:

Please use the following header for your solution:
`# [Language]: [Byte count] - [Sum of lengths] = [Total score]`.

Please include an explanation to your answer.

---

Miscelaneous:

I think this is a simple, yet fun, challenge. I've searched the site, and I haven't found a related challenge. If there's one, please point me.

I tried sometime ago to post a challenge, and I wasn't careful enough before posting (hence, I deleted it). I'd like to post a good first challenge. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the possible results are very small, so this challenge may not be that interesting. (They are: `1979339333, 1979339339, 23399339, 29399999, 37337999, 4391339, 59393339, 6133373, 6733919, 6733997, 73939133, 839, 9719`, for a total of -63.) Be aware that most golf languages will get a score near -63 just by brute forcing.

Comment: @japh That may be. I just thought it would be fun. Maybe a "King of the Hill" dinámica would work? Bots competing to eliminate opponents generating primes? (Like the game mentioned in the linked post)

Answer (score 0):

There are 1000 phones in a city. Add some switches so that we can freely decide linking pairs (Any amount of pairs). Two phones are connected iff some closed switches directly or indirectly link them.

In graph-theoretic terms, phones and "new points" are vertices, switches/links are edges, and you need to construct a graph with least number of edges such that for all possible list of pairs of the "phone"-vertices, there exists a configuration of the switches (subgraph), such that vertices in the same pair are in the same connected component, and vice versa.

You need to answer with:

1. A list of links, where 0~999 are the 1000 phones, and 1000~ are just point.
2. A program that take some pairs of phone ids, where no two numbers are same, and output the switches that need to be closed. It should run on tio in 60s.

Fewest switches win.

A sample solution may be:

```
1. [(i,j) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000,1500)]
2. def f(a):
     print ([(a[i][0],1000+i)for i in range(len(a))]+[(a[i][1],1000+i)for i in range(len(a))])
```

Which uses 500000 switches.

SN.

1. Should I require that when a connection is added or removed, there's a series of moves so that no other connections are affected?
2. Directly using [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) for \$\mathcal O(n \log^2 n)\$ seems to use more switches than \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ solution. Should I have more phones?

Answer (score 0):

### I'll Just Make A Snake

I noticed a post (now deleted) that pointed out that [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), when called with no arguments and non-empty input, will make a "snake" using the input:

```
Not sure what to do now with the input, so I'll just make a snake:


*****
    *
    *
    *
*****
*    
*    
*    
*
```

Cute, and seems simple enough. However, the snake generation has a few quirks that I thought would make an interesting challenge to replicate.

## The Challenge

When given a non-empty string as input, a snake is generated using the following algorithm:

1. If the input string is shorter than 17 characters, pad the string with duplicates of itself until its length is >= 17.
2. Generate a snake segment by replacing the non-space characters of the pattern with characters from the input string, following the direction of the snake. (Print characters right-to-left 5, up-to-down 3, left-to-right 5, up-to-down 4.)
3. If there is a previous snake segment generated, replace its last line with the first line of this segment.
4. Remove the used characters from the string.
5. Discard the first character of the remainder of the string. If there is no remainder, instead set the remainder to the original input string, minus its first character.
6. Pad the string with copied of the original input string until its length is >= 17.
7. Repeat steps 2-6 N times, where N = Length of input string.
8. Return the generated snake.

You do not have to handle empty inputs or non-string inputs.

You do not have to print the beginning message "Not sure what to do now with the input, so I'll just make a snake:".

*Note: 05AB1E (legacy) actually has some different behavior when given a base-10 integer as input. We will be ignoring that and treating all inputs as strings.*

## General rules:

- Input and output may be in any reasonable format.
- Trailing spaces and/or a single trailing newline are acceptable.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes for each language wins. No answer will be marked as *the* answer.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) apply.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. TIO).
- Adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

## Test Cases

Here is an (ungolfed) Python 2 program which replicates this behavior, for clarity and generation of additional test cases.

```python
pattern = """{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}\n    {5}\n    {6}\n    {7}\n{12}{11}{10}{9}{8}\n{13}\n{14}\n{15}\n{16}"""

def print_snake(in_str):
    print "Not sure what to do now with the input, so I'll just make a snake:\n\n"
    l = len(in_str)

    snek = [0]

    if l < 19:
        d,m = divmod(19, l)
        if m:
            d+=1
        in_str = in_str * d

    print_str, lost_char, rem = in_str, "", ""

    for i in range(l):
        print_str = rem + in_str
        print_str, lost_char, rem = print_str[:17], print_str[17], print_str[18:]
        snek.pop()
        snek += (pattern.format(*print_str)).split("\n")

    print "\n".join(snek)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLJbsIwEIbveYqRL7UhijCULSqH9tZLXwAQihrTGBI7ik1RZeXZ04mBhC6WbM3yzzfeyi@baTVumjKxVlQKVkAIcaPa8dqNazep3WO9UYDDTW/G7GbM0XAcZRzVHIuWtVv42MSvj36d@nVWIzgIUrGHspLK7oxKjoJKtTO2YnHQAn0CyJu2YE6VgHOWWLAaUg1Kn@EsbQY2EyBVebIhGA2vD3kOh5OxUCANEvDUeKM2inhkjifKhbr1CXzQKHHE@Hq0vfhyj7on4MvLNtqRhgUqUvlZ6JTyZQg563IoL3qlVw9XvE/7Vlh9NQaQBv3x2hDStLG79yxBsxJFpw3x9tt50e91BRIzUCXqQ9Cc9U07FJa2gOEV8FfwT68ut475fBve@b/dRbztiO2lRaUuKfsRguEK6PX3RLjjIrF00CEYi0yZS0sJPggL7l8ZA9FBS0VbCmvuPwV5fiGs@QY)

```python
Input: *

Output:
*****
    *
    *
    *
*****
*
*
*
*

Input: AB

Output:
ABABA
    B
    A
    B
ABABA
B
A
B
ABABA
    B
    A
    B
ABABA
B
A
B
A

Input: 123456789

Output:
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
12345
    6
    7
    8
43219
5
6
7
8

Input: sadness*and*despair

Output:
sadne
    s
    s
    *
d*dna
e
s
p
rsadn
    e
    s
    s
*dna*
d
e
s
irsad
    n
    e
    s
dna*s
*
d
e
airsa
    d
    n
    e
na*ss
d
*
d
pairs
    a
    d
    n
a*sse
n
d
*
spair
    s
    a
    d
*ssen
a
n
d
espai
    r
    s
    a
ssend
*
a
n
despa
    i
    r
    s
senda
s
*
a
*desp
    a
    i
    r
endas
s
s
*
d*des
    p
    a
    i
ndasr
e
s
s
nd*de
    s
    p
    a
dasri
n
e
s
and*d
    e
    s
    p
asria
d
n
e
*and*
    d
    e
    s
sriap
a
d
n
s*and
    *
    d
    e
riaps
s
a
d
ss*an
    d
    *
    d
iapse
r
s
a
ess*a
    n
    d
    *
apsed
i
r
s
ness*
    a
    n
    d
psed*
a
i
r
dness
    *
    a
    n
sed*d
p
a
i
adnes
    s
    *
    a
ed*dn
s
p
a
i
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: How words get cut up seems a bit arbitrary and non-obvious.

Comment: @Beefster Yup, but that's exactly how it's done in 05AB1E. See for yourself: https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/Q8ExYkpeanFxVqJeSlaKanFBYmZRQA

Answer (score 0):

## What season is it?

I don't think we have a challenge for this yet, surprisingly. The closest ones are:

- [What season is it?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121796/64538) (bad, closed)
- [Determine Season](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164753/64538) (only uses months)

Output the current season, using the astronomical definitions:

- Spring begins on the day of the spring equinox
- Summer begins on the summer solstice
- Fall begins on the fall equinox
- Winter begins on the winter solstice

You may use the northern or southern hemisphere dates.

### Input

None (use the current date).

### Output

One of these strings (case insensitive):
`spring`, `summer`, `fall` (or `autumn`), `winter`.

Your program must finish in a reasonable (less than 1 day) amount of time.

---

## Problems

- Is calculating the dates of the equinoxes/solstices too difficult? (I don't want the best solution to involve a big lookup table)
- What range of years should this be required to work in?
- Should the output format be less strict? ("Any 4 distinct values" rather than the season names)

Comment: I deide to upvote the old one and downvote this one

Comment: They're sufficiently different so I think it's ok for both to exist.

Comment: However looking at the wikipedia "Equinox" page, it mentions "However, because the Moon [...]" (second paragraph), which interpretation should be chosen?

Comment: Is there any range of date that it's ok to be wrong outside the range? (say, 1~2 century? I don't know how the motion of the Earth/Sun will change in some million years)

Comment: To your last question: I would say yes as the core of this challenge appears to be figuring out where the current date lies in relation to the solstices/equinoxes and translating that to specific strings doesn't, in my opinion, really add anything to the challenge.

Comment: I guess this should use the second interpretation, since it seems to be easier to calculate and more commonly used. I'll probably allow errors of a few minutes, in the event that the equinox/solstice occurs near midnight where a small rounding error might affect the result.

Comment: int main(){print("summer");} // guaranteed to be random

Answer (score 0):

## [Surreal Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)

Surreal numbers are one way of describing numbers using sets. In this challenge you will determine the value of a surreal number.

## Intro

A surreal number consists of two sets: a left and right. The value of the surreal number must be greater than all numbers in the left set and less than all numbers in the right set. We define 0 as having nothing in each set, which we write as `{|}`. Each surreal number also has a birth date. 0 is born on day 0. On each successive day, new surreal numbers are formed by taking the numbers formed on previous days and placing them in the left/right sets of a new number. For example, `{0|} = 1` is born on day 1, and `{|0} = -1` is also born on day 1.

To determine the value of a surreal number, we find the number "between" the left and right sets that was born earliest. As a general rule of thumb, numbers with lower powers of 2 in their denominator are born earlier. For example, the number `{0|1}` (which is born on day 2 by our rules) is equal to `1/2`, since 1/2 has the lowest power of 2 in its denominator between 0 and 1. In addition, if the left set is empty, we take the largest possible value, and vice versa if the right set is empty. For example, `{3|} = 4` and `{|6} = 5`.

*Note that `4` and `5` are just symbols that represent the surreal number, which just happen to align with our rational numbers if we define operations in a certain way.*

Some more examples:

```
{0, 1|} = {1|} = {-1, 1|} = 2
{0|3/4} = 1/2
{0|1/2} = 1/4
{0, 1/32, 1/16, 1/2 |} = 1
```

**To the Sandbox:** is this explanation clear? Anything I should add? I want to make sure of this before proposing the challenge.

Comment: The definition is not sufficient for uniquely determine the value. Why is `{1|} = 2` and not 3? (they both have power of 2 in the denom = 0)

Comment: @user202729 because 2 is born before 3.

Comment: Obviously {1|} is born before {{1|}|}. But what states {1|} is 2 and {{1|}|} is 3? (that's by definition, but what is the defnition?

Comment: @Quintec I had to check wikipedia to understand what is going on. I think it is worth explaining that we are *redefining* the symbols `1,2,-1,3,3/4` etc in a way that has nothing to do with the integers/rationals. But as it turns out later we are "lucky" and they happen to behave just like the integers/rationals we are used to if we choose the "right" addition and multiplication.

Comment: You might provide the exact form of \$f(\frac a{2^b})\$ which day the number is created, if that's not a part to solve

Comment: @l4m2 Actually I have a sandbox challenge for that: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9962/17602

Comment: @Neil I guess you also might. You mean to let users write short code to solve it, and a mathematical expression won't matter much

Comment: @user202729 Is it more clear now?

Comment: @flawr Added a note, though I'm not sure if it gets the point across accurately

Comment: You should take the largest possible value with the smallest birthdate. (i.e., the largest possible value is a tiebreaker)

Comment: The I/O seems completely undefined. Is the input something isomorphic to two finite lists of rationals with denominators which are powers of two, and the output a rational with denominator which is a power of two?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes, I haven't defined the IO yet, just wanted to make sure people understood the concept of surreal numbers. The input will be a list of two arrays, which represent the left and right sets of the surreal number. Inside the left and right sets there may be surreal numbers or regular rationals.

Comment: I'd suggest limiting this to surreal representations of integers or else this will be a nightmare to deal with.

Comment: @Beefster Dyadic rationals aren't that hard.

Answer (score 0):

## Check List for Duplicates

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a non-empty list of integers, return a truthy value if all entries are unique, and a falsey value of there are duplicate entries (or vice versa).

#### Examples

```
[1,2,3] -> false
[1,1,3] -> true
[1] -> false
[1,3,1,5] -> true
```

**META:** I couldn't find this as a challenge, but I cannot believe we didn't allready have this. Let me know if you can find anything related.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28359/determine-if-all-decimal-digits-are-unique/28365#28365)

Comment: I expect this to be one byte in Jelly.

Comment: @Adám It's 2 bytes long, actually.

Comment: Hm, no Iit is so trivial, that everybody assumed it already exists… We have lots of related (and more interesting) challenges.

Comment: Can the input contain `0`s or negative integers? Can we take input as an array/list of strings? Should the 2 outputs be consistent?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171615/58974)

Comment: (Both my Japt solution and my second JS solution there would work for this, without any modifications)

Comment: let x=|v| v.iter().unique().count()>0   even short in Rust! but i would kind of like to see if one of the esolangs could get it down to 1 byte, though. would be fun.

Answer (score 0):

## Hearts [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Goal: build the bot to play the classic card game [Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts).

### The Rules

- Four players per game
- Played with a standard deck of 52 cards (in the protocol, 11 = J, 12 = Q, 13 = K, 14 = A)
- Object: finish the game with the least points
- Each game consists of many rounds, each of which consist of 13 tricks
- At the beginning of a round, each player is dealt 13 cards
- Then, each player passes three cards to an opponent:

  - Round 1: Pass to opponent 1 (to your left)
  - Round 2: Pass to opponent 2 (across the table)
  - Round 3: Pass to opponent 3 (to your right)
  - Round 4: No passing occurs
  - Round 5 is the same as round 1, and so on
- The player with the two of clubs plays it, beginning the first trick. The suit of the first card played in a trick is the "leading suit."

  - Each other player adds a card to the trick (clockwise). If they have any cards of the leading suit, they must play them; otherwise, they can play any card. (Exception: hearts and the queen of spades cannot be played in the first trick.)
  - The player who played the highest card **in the leading suit** takes the trick, adding its cards to their collection of taken cards (distinct from their hand)
  - The player who took the trick then begins the next trick with any card from their hand. (Exception: A player may not begin a trick with hearts until a heart or the queen of spades has already been played.)
- After 13 tricks, the round ends. Each player gains points for their taken cards:

  - 1 point per heart
  - 13 points for the queen of spades
  - 0 points for all other cards
  - Exception: If a player would gain 26 points (i.e. they took every heart and the queen of spades), every other player gains 26 points instead.
- Another round begins. This continues until a player has ≥100 points at the end of a round. At this point, the player with the lowest score wins (if there is a tie, extra rounds are played until there is no longer a tie).

### The Protocol

Your program can be in any language (that I can run on macOS without too much fuss). It communicates using newline-separated JSON messages on stdin/stdout.

Messages your program receives:

- `{"request": "pass", "direction": "left", "state": {...}}` (other directions: `right`, `across`)
- `{"request": "play", "state": {...}}`

Expected responses:

- `{"action": "pass", "cards": [{"suit": "hearts", "number": 14}, {"suit": "hearts", "number": 13}, {"suit": "hearts", "number": 12}]}`
- `{"action": "play", "card": {"suit": "hearts", "number": 14}}`

The state object:

```
{
    "hand": [cards...],
    "taken": {playerId: [cards...]},
    "scores": {playerId: number}, // Does not include the current round
    "currentScores": {playerId: number}, // Points earned so far this round
    "tricks": [tricks...] // The current trick is the last object in this array.
}
```

The trick object:

```
{
    "leader": playerId, // The player who started the trick
    "leadSuit": "hearts", // or spades, clubs, diamonds
    "played": {playerId: card},
    "winner": playerId // Missing for the current trick
}
```

You always see the same player numbers: you are player 0, player 1 is to your left, player 2 is across from you, and player 3 is to your right.

Comment: Good idea for a [tag:king-of-the-hill]. Do you have the controller written yet? If not, I think JSON is a bit overkill.

Comment: Controller not written yet. Disagree about the JSON—IMO, JSON is a lot easier to deal with than a custom format (especially since I’m passing the full state each time—I could probably set up a passable format for just the events without JSON, but then players would need to track the game state themselves)

Comment: When building the controller, you should be sure to allow a player to play a heart in any case if their only cards are hearts and the Queen of Spades (That's not in your rules, but it's kind of an obvious exception).

Comment: @Spitemaster good catch

Answer (score 0):

**Smallest Working Result - Referenced Reduction** [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

**RULES**

1. Function must accept a keyed data structure
2. Function must return a modified version of that keyed data structure.
3. Function cannot use any libraries
4. Function will be tested against linked file.
5. Function must work against other similarly formatted files (no having a function that pops out a static answer!)

**SCORING**

1. To score, must be able to be run against multiple inputted keyed arrays.
2. To score, returned array must be able to be reverse-engineered into original array (conversion must be lossless).
3. Score will be determined by a keyed array built off of attached CSV (based off the oxford dictionary).
4. Score is to return an array with the fewest unique referenced keys.

**DESCRIPTION**

Build a function that does the following: 
It pulls in a keyed data structure (dictionary, keyed array, object, etc. depending on your languages' primary keyed reference structure) of the following structure...

```
ID   |  REF 1   |   REF 2   |   REF 3   | ...
1    |  
2    |   1      |   35      |   1
3    |   1      |   2       |   5       |
4    |   FOO    |   7       |   21      |
5    |   FOO    |   9       |           |   
6    |          |           |           |
7    |          |           |
BAR  |   6      |   6       |   6
8    |   BAR    |   BAR
...
```

Each object is made of and unrestricted number of references to other objects (that may or may not be in the table), or are 'prime' objects that reference nothing. Prime objects cannot be reduced. Objects that reference objects not in the table obviously cannot be fully reduced. Further, an object may not directly reference itself.

The goal is to have the fewest things referenced possible.

For example, a table like:

```
ID   |  REF 1   |   REF 2   |   REF 3   | ...
1    |   
2    |   1      |   1       |   7
3    |   1      |   2       |   1       |
4    |   3      |   1       |   3       |
5    |   1      |   3       |   3       |
6    |   1      |   4       |   FOO     |
7    |
```

Could be reduced to:

```
ID   |  REF 1      |   REF 2                   |   REF 3     | ...
1    |  
2    |   1         |   1                       |   7
3    |   1         |   (1,1, 7)                |   1         |
4    | (1(1,1, 7)1)|   1                       |  (1(1,1,7)1)|
5    |   1         |  (1(1,1,7)1)              |  (1(1,1,7)1)|
6    |   1         |((1(1,1,7)1),1(1(1,1,7)1)) |   FOO       |
7    |
```

(Notice, although the returned array is bigger and multidimensional, it actually has fewer references in it. While the first has 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, and FOO in the ref columns, the reduced table only has the unique values 1, 7, and FOO.)

The result is scored by the result that has the fewest unique items referenced while still being able to re-create the original table.

And to test, it's going to have a csv of the complete Oxford Dictionary thrown at it that's been converted to a keyed array. (I've uploaded a csv of it here: http://joshup.com/experiments/Oxford_English_Dictionary.csv, each word being the ID, and the following words being the references. Note, file is still being cleaned up, plan to clean before challenge gets moved from sandbox to main area.)

Although the examples are fairly straightforward, the code puzzler is reminded that this will be tested against an array built form the Oxford Dictionary using the word as the key, and the full description of the word as the array (each word being an array item, and, potentially a key somewhere else in the array). This means there is a very real chance that unlike the examples, arrays will reference eachother quite frequently, creating large loops of refrences between them, and the puzzle solver is reminded that choosing which key to reduce other keys into to will likely have a large impact on the final set of unique references.

Comment: Will self references be removed from the test data?

Comment: @trichoplax No, they won't.

Answer (score 0):

## IPv6 Aggregator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The goal is to aggregate a list of ipv6 subnets into a smaller list.

#### Rules:

- The input is a list of ipv6 subnets in the extended format (such as 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/48)
- The output must be the optimal
- The output list can be either in extended format, or using any valid compression
- The output list can be unsorted
- The value of irrelevant bits is not important (both ::1/127 and ::0/127 are considered valid)

#### Examples:

```
[2001:0db8:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/48,
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/48,
2001:0db8:0000:000f:0000:0000:0000:0000/48,
2001:0db8:0000:000e:0000:0000:0000:0000/48]
will become
[2001:0db8:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000/47,
2001:0db8:000e:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000/47]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Index and Get/Set Nested Arrays/Lists

This question is intended as extension of [Home on the Range of Lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/home-on-the-range-of-lists/).

This challenge is to write one or two functions or a program which are getter and setter for a nested array/list mapped to 0-based or 1-based indexing.

## Input

An array/list containing at least one nested array/list (length of `2`) where each first element of successive nested arrays is set to either 0-based or 1-based indexes corresponding to each array. Each array is initialized with the first element set to the respective index of the full array.

Example

```
2 => [0, [1]]
     (0) (1) // 0-based indexing
6 => [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]]
     (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) // 1-based indexing
```

## Rules

- If one function is used the second parameter must be the getter for the element value. If only two arguments are passed the function (input, index to get) acts as the getter. If three arguments are passed, the second argument acts as a getter and the third argument acts as a setter.
- If two functions are used one function acts as a getter exclusively and the second function acts as a setter exclusively. The first argument to the function is the index to get, the second argument is the value to set at the index passed at the first argument.
- If the array/list prototype is modified to chain the method to the rules above still apply.
- The functions are not expected to push to or splice from values in the input array/list.

## Output

- Where a getter is used the value of that index of the array/list.
- Where a setter is used the complete array/list after setting the index to the passed value.

## Test cases

(Single function acting as both getter and setter, where `f` is the single function)

Setter (0-based indexing)

```
f([0, [1]], 1, 7) => [0, [7]]
```

Setter (1-based indexing)

```
f([0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]], 6, 'map') => [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, ['map']]]]]]
```

Getter (1-based indexing)

```
f([0, [1, [2, [3, [4, ['map']]]]]], 6) => 'map'
```

(Two functions, `get` and `set`, 1-based indexing)

```
get([0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]], 4) => 3

set([0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]], 4, 'set') => [0, [1, [2, ['set', [4, [5]]]]]]
```

(Modifying `Array` (or equivalent in the language used prototype) 0-based indexing)

```
[0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]].get(4) => 4

[0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]].set(4, 'set') => [0, [1, [2, [3, ['set', [5]]]]]]
```

## Winning criteria

Least amount of bytes in the language used.

---

Tags: 'code-golf' 'array-manipulation'

Comment: `1.` Requiring inputs to be in a particular order is too restricting, you should remove that. `2.` Are we guaranteed that the value to be set is either an positive integer (`>0`) or a non-empty string? You should specify the possible values we'd be expected to handle.

Comment: @Shaggy 1) What do you mean by a particular order? That is the input data structure, for consistency. Had this user not been consistent as to input then users would have stated the input is not clear. The input is stable and clear. Can you provide examples of the input that you are contemplating that is not at the question? 2) No, the value set can be any value the language used has available to set. Do you suggest making that restrictive? The data structure must remain the same. A single value at index "0" of each nested array with a nested array at index "1" of that array, except the last.

Comment: @Shaggy What edits to the question do you suggest?

Comment: If a language has no support for nested lists but there's a way to implement them be scored? Will they need to include the datastructure's implementation in their bytecount?

Comment: @BMO Not sure what you mean by "the datastructure's implementation"? Importing a library to achieve the output? If a user is able to implement the requirement using strings, that suffices. A valid `JSON` string can be converted to an array/list. Implementing the getter and setter might be interesting, though should be possible.

Comment: I had Haskell in mind, meant something [like this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyWxJFHBL7W4JDXFJ7O4RCFRwVbBNbegpFKhRsE1JzU3NQ8kFo2sIpZLAQhSUosyyzLz0hWCM/LL/@cmZuYBdRYUZQLVq8B1GipEw5hGCKaxQnSsAhD@BwA "Haskell – Try It Online") since [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvRCHaUCfaSCfaOFYBCP//BwA) is not allowed. But good call with strings.

Comment: @BMO The expected output for the first example would be `[Element 1 [Element 2 [Element 3 [Element 4]]]]`. The second example is valid. There is an additional requirement to create getter and setter to get and set each element either using 0-based or 1-based indexes. If that is achievable using strings, yes, the answer is allowed.

Comment: @BMO For example, using JavaScript with String methods and without Array methods this is possible [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4hOkGvKLUgNbFEI08TxMpJTE7V0I@J1k/X0cjVydQEKlGpztXOrFWpzrTJ0zW0V9dRt1JXr03Q1E6IRdL7Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DSFPTWgFVyAwo9B8A). The example does not include a getter or setter, though should be possible using only string methods.

Answer (score 0):

## This is not the Timing Attack you are looking for!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)

---

### Introduction

I recently was writing a piece of code to verify a [HMAC signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) (to verify an API request). While doing that I found the given method in the documentation to be "incredibly verbose" and as a somewhat as a somewhat active PPCG member, that's obviously something that needs to be "fixed"! However being also an active member of [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) I know that HMAC tag verification needs to expose *secret independent timing* (a.k.a. "needs to be constant time") because otherwise an attacker may just brute-force a valid tag with a couple of dozen / hundred queries checking each time up to which byte was correct.

### The input

The input is two strings `a` and `b` which are guaranteed to be of the same length and encoding.

### The output

The output is a truthy or falsey value.

### What to do?

You return a truthy output if `a` and `b` have the same content and a falsey value otherwise.

### That sounds too easy, where's the catch!?

Your code must exhibit *secret independent timing*, that is the runtime of your code may not depend on the actual values of the two strings. To be valid your answer *must* provide a convincing argument that the execution time is independent of the secret values. To help you, I've listed a helpful guidelines:

- For secret-independent timing it is sufficient to use a non secret independent comparison on the HMAC of both strings under a fresh random key.
- For secret-independent timing there must not be early (loop-) returns or operations that are not evaluated due to short circuiting semantics (assuming you operate on the actual strings).
- For secret-independent timing the values must not be used as array indices or for similar lookups as timing variation can happen due to caching.
- For secret-independent timing the value must not contribute to control-flow decisions, e.g. as a condition for a `while` or `if` or as an operand to a short-circuiting `&&`.
- For secret-independent timing the value must not contribute to operands to multplication or division instructions.

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes per language that satisfies the I/O and the runtime behavior wins!

Comment: At least points (2) to (4) - probably also (5) - are [non-observable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/48198) requirements for some languages. For example, what counts as control-flow decision contributing value in brainfuck?

Comment: might want to dumb it down a little (i.e. explain jargon) for slow folks like me

Answer (score 0):

## KoTH: Iterated Nash bargaining!

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

---

In this king of the hill challenge, you must play an iterated [Nash bargaining game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargaining_problem).
You and your opponent must return a number between 1 and 100 which says how much money out of £100 you want.

If the total amount requested by the players is less than £100, both players get their request. If their total request is greater than that available, neither player gets their request. However, to spice things up, it is iterated — you will play 200 rounds against each opponent.

Your bot should be a Python 3.7 function that takes 4 inputs in the following order: your current points, your opponent's current points, all moves you have played (in a list) and all moves your opponent has played so far (also a list).

Here are two examples, one plays the opponents last move (and 50 on the first move):

```python
def copycat(themp, myp, theml, myl):
    if len(theml) < 1:
        return 50
    else:
        return theml[-1]
```

The other plays 50 if they have less than 50 points, and 70 otherwise:

```python
def fiftyseventybot(thempoints, mepoints, themlist, mylist):
    if thempoints <= 50:
        return 50
    else:
        return 70
```

Your bot will play 200 rounds against each opponent, in the 'round robin' fashion .Whoever ends up with the most points wins. Standard loopholes are banned.

Have fun!

---

### Sandbox

This is my first question, make sure to tell me if anything could be worded better or if anything is spelled wrong etc.

Also tell me whether you think this is a good idea and if you have any ideas to add to it.

Is there not enough of an incentive to change if both players are going 50?
if so, what incentives could be created?

There seems to be disagreement between @PeterTaylor and @Spitemaster. I would like to reach some kind of consensus on this. Could anyone possibly comment on what they think?

Comment: It seems to me that this won't work - neither player has any incentive to play anything other than 50.

Comment: Agreed; furthermore, upon gaining an advantage on an opponent, it only makes sense to play greater than 50 every turn so that either you gain more points or neither of you gain any points so that you end with more points than them.

Comment: @Sebastian I can see why you would say that, but as you are trying to gain the most points over all rounds (playing every bot) you would want to maximise your score, meaning that tactic would lose you potential points as it relies on both of you not getting any points not being a bad outcome.(sorry that was quite a bad way of putting it but I hope you get my point)

Comment: @spitemaster I originally thought that if you went for a higher number, you could try to force the opponent down, and you could use small numbers by finding when bots are constant and you’ve got no chance etc. Maybe there needs to be some kind of short term incentive for going high, like, for example, in the prisoners dilemma?

Comment: The very idea of a Nash equilibrium is that neither player has an incentive to change. I don't think this is a good thing upon which to base a challenge.

Comment: I think it might end up with interesting answers if there are any bots which do not actually aim for equilibrium. It depends on whether the bot cares more for maximizing its own score or minimizing the amount the other bot gets as an advantage

Comment: @Spitemaster, I can tell you from personal experience in earlier [tag:king-of-the-hill] games that playing a Nash equilibrium may get you a fairly high position in these iterated games but it never wins. The winner usually plays a strategy which has a worse mean but high variance until they get an advantage, and *then* switches to the equilibrium.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In games like the Prisoner's Dilemma, the Nash equilibrium is defect.  As there are ways of getting more points for both players, it is advantageous to not play that and instead try something semi-cooperative.  In this game, there is no strategy that would be advantageous over the Nash equilibrium if both bots cooperated.  For a bot to beat the 50 bot, you'd have to have a majority of bots willingly lose to either the bot that would win or the 50 bot.

Comment: @Spitemaster, in practice that's not a problem.

Comment: Maybe changing the amount of money from 100 to 99 or any other odd number would solve it?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Thats a good idea. It certainly would improve things but you might just get bots switching between rounded down and up halves only

Comment: Or maybe a restriction that you can't play the same number more than 3 times in a row?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I'm definitely going to implement your idea about an odd number, I think I might just change it to 99. However banning playing the same number all of the time wouldn't make a difference to too many bots just, in this example ,playing 50 and 49.

Answer (score 0):

## Restoration by patching [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

Given a list of signed floating-point numbers and missing values denoted with a consistent value that doesn't represent a signed floating-point number of your language's natural signed float type (e.g. NaN, +∞, -∞, null/undefined/None, char, string, int/long, unsigned float, double, etc. as long as you can separate it from a real signed float), patch the list so that it only contains floats. Here's how you patch the list:

1. For each run of missing values:

   1. Take the mean of the value that precedes the run to the value that follows it.
   2. Patch the run:

      - If the run has an odd length, replace its middle element with that mean.
      - If the run has an even length, replace its two middle elements with that mean.
2. If there still are missing values, go to step 1.

The input denotes data points, and some of them are missing, so you want to patch them. Please note that this method of restoring lost stats isn't recommended for everything.

Your solution must not make use of [some stuff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024).

#### Example: `[1.0, _, _, _, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, _, _, _, _, 12.0]`

"Patch X.Y" represents the Yth patch of the Xth iteration of the method above.

Patch 1.1: `[1.0, _, 3.0, _, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, _, _, _, _, 12.0]`.
Patch 1.2: `[1.0, _, 3.0, _, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, _, 9.5, 9.5, _, 12.0]`.

Patch 2.1: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, _, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, _, 9.5, 9.5, _, 12.0]`.
Patch 2.2: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, _, 9.5, 9.5, _, 12.0]`.
Patch 2.3: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.25, 9.5, 9.5, _, 12.0]`.
Patch 2.4: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.25, 9.5, 9.5, 10.75, 12.0]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Shenzhen I/O command encoder/decoder

The basic elements in Shenzhen I/O are:

```
P = p0 | p1
X = x0 | x1 | x2 | x3
R = acc | dat | P | X | null
L = 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 15
V = R | -999 | -998 | -997 | ... | 998 | 999
```

`acc | dat | X` are registers containing number between -999 and 999, and `P` between 0 and 100, but you can't know them in advance. `null` is register that writing anything into it has no effect, and reading from it provides `0`.

The command set is:

```
nop     nothing
mov V R R:=V
jmp L   unreplacable
slp V   sleep for max{V,0} seconds
slx X   unreplacable
add V   acc:=acc+V
sub V   acc:=acc-V
mul V   acc:=acc*V
not     unreplacable
dgt V   acc:=Tth decimal digit and sign if V in {0,1,2} else 0
dst V V set V1th decimal digit and sign to lowest digit and sign
    (negative/non-negative) of V2 if V1 in {0,1,2} else nothing
teq V V s:=1 if V1=V2 else s:=2
tgt V V s:=1 if V1>V2 else s:=2
tlt V V s:=1 if V1<V2 else s:=2
tcp V V s:=1 if V1>V2; s:=2 if V1<V2; s:=0 otherwise
gen P V V
        P:=100, sleep for max{V1,0} seconds,
        P:=0, sleep for max{V2,0} seconds
```

Only `mov` can take two same elements in P or X.

Now you're to encode each command into two bytes. If two commands do exactly same thing they are replacable, but:

1. If element(s) in P and X appear, the existance matters. E.g. `mov acc null` = `nop`, but `dst 8 x1` = `mov x1 null` != `nop`
2. If multiple elements are in P and X, the order matters. E.g. `teq acc p1` = `teq p1 acc`, but `teq p1 p0` != `teq p0 p1`
3. Reading from P also writes 0 to P; Writing any negative to P equals to writing 0 to P, and writing number larger than 100 equals to writing one equal to 100. E.g. `mov p1 null` = `mov 0 p1` = `mov -43 p1`
4. For sleep function we don't need to consider what happen after 1800 seconds. i.e. `gen p0 900 901` = `gen p0 900 900` != `gen p0 900 899`

You need to write an encoder(turning a command into 21 bits, or to say an integer between 0 and 2^21-1) and a decoder(vise versa). Smallest sum of length of encoder and decoder win.

A command checker and equivment finder(two equal commands are mapped to same one) is below: (Spoiler) (WIP)

```js
alert('WIP');
```

```html
<input id="vin" maxlength="20" onchange="foo()" onkeyup="foo()"><br><span id="vout">
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode)

P.s. I changed the definition of `L` to allow single line command

Comment: What is [Shenzhen I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhen_I/O)? Why would I care about `I` it doesn't appear anywhere? What is the input of a decoder, what is the input of an encoder? It's hard to tell what this challenge is about.. Is it about encoding/compression, decoding/parsing? Sum of length of what (encoded program or encoder and decoder)?

Comment: @BMO Who care what SZIO is. `I` appear in `V`. Input a command and output two bytes. Vise versa. It should be a encoding/decoding for you can decide your own encoding rule

Comment: Ah I didn't see that, my bad. I would add an motivation or at the very least a link, st. people know what Shenzhen I/O is. Rules should be ok, I think.

Comment: But this is not possible to encode in 2 bytes, not even `dst V V` only: `V` can be \$2000\$ values, for that I will need \$\lceil \log_2 2000 \rceil = 11\$ bits, to encode the tuple (`V1`,`V2`) I will need \$22\$ bits plus two bits for `+-@ `. Total is: \$24\$ bits which is more than two bytes. And this doesn't even account for the encoding of `dst` itself.

Comment: @BMO If two commands do exactly same thing they are replacable, and dst only have 297 possible behaviors

Comment: You should assume that people have no knowledge about this assembly language. What are the semantics of `+-@ `? Would `mov null acc = nop` (the current rules seem to suggest so, but my intuition tells me otherwise)? etc. Also, I'm not convinced that it's possible to encode each instruction (or an equivalent thereof) in 2 bytes, are you certain that it's possible?

Comment: @BMO Th `+-@ ` are just there for purposes unrelated to this challenge. Since "null is register that reading from it provides 0" it equals to `mov 0 acc`

Comment: @BMO Should I remove the `+-@ ` part and allow only 14 bits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88221/discussion-between-bmo-and-l4m2).

Answer (score 0):

### Write a negadecimal number in words.

[Negadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negadecimal) is a numeral system with digits \$0\$ to \$9\$ but is base \$-10\$ instead of \$10\$. Here are some examples (the left side is decimal numeral, and the right side is a negadecimal numeral):

$$
\begin{array}{rcrl}
    0 & \to &   0 & \\
    1 & \to &   1 & \\
    9 & \to &   9 & \\
   10 & \to & 190 &  \bigl(1 \cdot 100 + 9 \cdot (-10) + 0 \cdot 1 \bigr) \\
   11 & \to & 191 & \\
   20 & \to & 180 & \\
   99 & \to & 119 & \\
  100 & \to & 100 & \\
   -1 & \to &  19 & \\
   -9 & \to &  11 & \\
  -10 & \to &  10 & \\
  -11 & \to &  29 &  \bigl(2 \cdot (-10) + 9 \cdot 1 \bigr)
\end{array}
$$

Basically, the carry rule (for both addition and subtraction) is that if you add one to nine, it wraps around to zero and you *subtract* one from the digit to the left, and if you subtract one from zero, it wraps around to nine, and you *add* one to the digit to the left. Also note that you can add or remove leading zeros from a number without changing its value. (In particular, the empty string represents the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum), i.e. zero.)

### Challenge

Anyways, for the actual challenge, **you will take an integer as input and convert it to negadecimal. Then you will convert that to *words*.** What do I mean by that?

The digits \$0\$ to \$9\$ have their regulars names (i.e. `zero`, `one`, ..., `nine`).
The negadecimal numbers \$10\$ through \$90\$ (i.e. negative ten through negative ninety) have the following names:

```
onetao, twotao, threetao, fourtao, fivetao, sixtao, seventao, eighttao, ninetao
```

The negadecimal numbers \$100\$ to \$900\$ have their regular names (i.e. `one hundred`, `two hundred`, ..., `nine hundred`).

Numbers that are a digit followed by three or more zeros are created by combining the above names. For example, negadecimal \$2000\$ is `twotao hundred`, \$40000\$ is `four hundred hundred`, \$300000\$ is `threetao hundred hundred`, etc.

All other numbers are named by writing it in expanded notation, naming each summand (which will be one of the above), and conjuncting them. For example, negadecimal \$5402=5000 + 400 + 0 + 2\$ is `fivetao hundred, four hundred, and two.`

Zero summands are a special case. If the whole number is zero, you just write `zero`. Otherwise, you omit all zero summands.

### Examples

Here are some examples (the left side is a decimal numeral, and the right side is a negadecimal numeral noun):

```
0 → "zero"
10 → "one hundred and ninetao"
11 → "one hundred, ninetao, and one"
-11 → "twotao and nine"
-10 → "onetao"
-9 → "onetao and one"
101 → "one hundred and one"
999999997 → "ninetao hundred hundred hundred hundred, nine hundred hundred hundred hundred, ninetao hundred hundred hundred, nine hundred hundred hundred, ninetao hundred hundred, nine hundred hundred, ninetao hundred, nine hundred, ninetao, and seven."
```

This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Rather subjective: Interesting challenge, until I read "*Then you will convert that to words*" :(

Comment: The challenge is well explained, but it could be improved a lot with some minor formatting. Eg. use MathJax, make some paragraphs (intro,actual description, i/o rules, examples or the like). As it stands it's not very easy to read. Also by conjuncting do you mean join with `,` except for the last two with `and`? What about spaces, are they important?

Comment: @BMO What do you mean subjective? I specify exactly what I mean by convert to words later in the post.

Comment: @BMO Conjuncting means to join with commas, and then to insert `and` between the last and second to last item. If there are only two items, you omit the comma. If there is only one item, you omit the `and`.

Comment: My opinion is subjective: That I liked the first part of the challenge, but the second part not so much. Okay, got it maybe you could add that to the challenge and describe how the spacing works there. One question which should be answered (in the challenge) for example: Is the space after the `,` obligatory or can a solution omit it?

Comment: I reformatted the post (didn't change the wording), feel free to roll-back if you don't like it. Another question popped up when doing so: Some examples seem to have a `.` at the end, is this on purpose? If so you should explain when it is required. Also is lower-case important?

Answer (score 0):

## Super Permutations

Find the super permutation for a set of size n. A super permutation of a set is one string that contains all permutations of that set. Here is a helpful [video](https://youtu.be/OZzIvl1tbPo) by Matt Parker

## Example

For a set of size 2 all the permutations are `AB, BA` but the super permutation is `ABA` because it contains the string `AB` and `BA`.
For a set of 3 all permutations are `ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CBA,CAB` and the super permutation is `ABCABACBA`.

## Challenge

Given a certain size n (n>=1) find a super permutation of that set. To do this you have to use a pattern explained in the video.

## Input

An integer greater than 0. This can be a function input `superperm(n)` or be taken from user input.

## Output

super permutation of that sized set. This can either be printed out or the return value of a function

## Sample Inputs

all of these are the shortest for that length but this is not a requirement.

```
    1: A
    2: ABA
    3: ABCABACBA
    4: ABCDABCADBCABDCABADABACDBACBDACBADCBA
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the shortest length to be the requirement? As you stated yourself, just concatenating all permutations is trivial, but if this is a `[codegolf]` challenge, everyone will use that trivial approach to save (loads of) bytes. I know a few programming language which could get all permutations and join them in 2 bytes.. Finding the shortest permutation would prove more difficult however, and seems like a more interesting challenge tbh.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the problem with the shortest permutation is that it's not known about 7 or 8. There is a pattern that gives one of the shortest solutions so maybe you should be required to follow that.

Comment: This *feels* very dupey to me but I can't come up with the right search term(s) at the moment to find a possible target. I also agree with @KevinCruijssen on the scoring - some combination of byte count and length of output for a specific `n` would work better.

Comment: I don't know of a duplicate from before this sandbox answer was posted, but there is now a [superpermutation challenge on main that uses a different scoring mechanism to encourage shorter superpermutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179607/superpermutations)

Answer (score 0):

Recently i made a post, but jumped the gun a little... I posted it before getting feedback and ended up getting it put on hold for being too arbitrary, but I have finally come here to get it properly fixed. Also I just got my Meta User fixed, so now I can post here!

[Link to original post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179300/a-multipurpose-quine)

[Link to chat where all of this is being discussed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89081/discussion-on-question-by-krystostheoverlord-a-multipurpose-quine)

Basically I want to make the challenge where you create a quine that when given an input of 0 it outputs itself, and if given some other number it outputs a different quine.
For example, abc outputting abc if given 0, abc outputting gef if given 1, abc outputting qwerty when given 255 etc... The scoring will be based on how little bytes can be used and how many extra *different* quines that it can output.

The problem comes with defining what defines *different* quine and how to balance the scoring so that coders will be encouraged to write short code, but still try to create different quines that aren't just altered copies of the original or each other

**Examples of what not to do**

```
abc      //original
abcd     //output
abcabcabc//output
aabc     //output
aaabc    //output
aaabbbccc//output
```

stuff like this wouldn't be allowed, I just don't know how to turn that into a rule that can't be abused.

**What I want examples**

```
abc      //original
gefh     //output
qwetryiop//output
uiop     //output
kerdp    //output
tttuiiree//output
```

Basically all of the output quines are different from each other, nor are they similar

And of course no examining source code.

Comment: I would say output a quine without using the same characters from the previous quine but there is already a challenge like that

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz  Yes, that would work, but I want to see if there is another way to do this without branching away from the original challenge

Comment: Perhaps you can go back to the polyglot specs, and say that the outputted quines all have to be in different languages?

Comment: @JoKing That might just work, if I do that I'll have to change the scoring system so that it doesn't push too hard on golfing, but hard enough that people are encouraged to make small programs, and also to try and make it output as many quines as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Is This Randomizer Seed Beatable?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph)

---

Randomizers of Pokemon, Zelda, Metroid games (among other games) have gained a lot of popularity in the last few years within the speedrunning community. Basically these are programs that shuffle around items, Pokemon, and even cosmetic things in a ROM of the game. It gives speedrunners a new and exciting challenge for a game they have played perhaps hundreds of times since items affect progression and can lead them to play the game very differently.

Randomizers also have logic that prevents them from making unbeatable configurations. We'll be looking at a simple, but generalized, form of this logic in this challenge.

### Challenge Explanation

You will be given a list of rules as input describing some game world and its item requirements and a list of item locations. Your task is to determine if the item locations represent a beatable seed within the rules.

#### World Rules

The rules are a list of required items for accessing a location. A required item may have an associated quantity. For example, a simplified sampling of Super Metroid:

```
[] => Morph
[Morph] => BlueBrinstarBottomMissiles
[Missiles, Morph] => Bombs
[HighJump] => BlueBrinstarETank
[Morph, Bombs] => CrateriaDescentETank
...
[Supers, HighJump, Morph, Bombs] => Kraid
[Kraid] => Varia
[Varia] => Speed
[Varia, Speed] => IceBeam
...
[Kraid, Phantoon, Draygon, Ridley, Morph, IceBeam, Charge, 3 Missiles, 3 Supers, 3 ETank, Varia, Gravity] => END
```

It's possible for a location to be reachable by different sets of requirements. Conceptually, this means that any one set of requirements. Here's an example from Zelda: Ocarina of Time (referencing some glitches):

```
[DekuTreeBeaten] => ForestExit
[Stick] => ForestExit
[Nut] => ForestExit
[KokiriSword, DekuShield] => ForestExit
```

Keep in mind that the right hand side of the rules list in my example is actually a location id, not an item id. The special location id `END` indicates the ability to beat the game with those items.

#### Item Locations

You will receive a mapping of location IDs and which item they contain. For example:

```
KokiriSwordChest: HeartPiece
MidoHouse1: Hookshot
MidoHouse2: 5Rupees
...
DampeDig: ForestTempleBossKey
DampeRace1: NayrusLove
DampeRace2: HeartPiece
...
GoldGauntletsChest: DoubleMagic
...
```

### What does it mean to be beatable?

A player begins a game with no items. If it is possible for the player to, through the continued acquisition of available items, reach the `END` location, then the seed is beatable. It doesn't matter if all items are obtainable as long as the `END` location is reachable.

This maps to a variant of graph reachability problems which can be solved relatively easily with a breadth-first search. (Other approaches may work as well)

#### Simple example (beatable)

World Rules:

```
[] => SwordChest
[] => ShieldChest
[Sword, Shield] => FireballScroll
[Fireball] => IceBeamScroll
[Fireball, Sword] => LightningScroll
[Fireball, IceBeam, Lightning] => END
```

Item Locations:

```
SwordChest: Fireball
ShieldChest: Sword
FireballScroll: Shield
IceBeamScroll: Lightning
LightningScroll: IceBeam
```

This seed is beatable with this item order: Fireball, Sword, Lightning, IceBeam. It's impossible to get the Shield because it's locked behind the FireballScroll which requires the Shield. But that doesn't matter because the `END` only requires the three elemental spells.

#### Simple example (unbeatable)

World Rules:

```
[] => SwordChest
[] => ShieldChest
[Sword, Shield] => FireballScroll
[Fireball, Shield] => IceBeamScroll
[Fireball, Sword] => LightningScroll
[Fireball, IceBeam, Lightning] => END
```

Item Locations:

```
SwordChest: Fireball
ShieldChest: Shield
FireballScroll: Sword
IceBeamScroll: Lightning
LightningScroll: IceBeam
```

This seed is unbeatable because Lightning is required, but is locked behind the Ice Beam Scroll, which requires the sword, which in turn is locked behind the Fireball Scroll, which itself requires the sword to access.

#### More test cases

More test cases can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Beefster09/37f9595a5d37bb6df72091d6f130e419).

### Other Notes and Rules

- You can accept the world rules and the item locations in any convenient format or representation, given these restrictions:

  - When multiples of one item are in a requirements list, you can represent it by repeating that item multiple times *or* by having a quantity and item id.
  - Both item and location ids must be taken in as alphanumeric strings. (i.e. no converting it to numbers or other more convenient values before passing it into your program/function)
  - The sentinel value for the "beating the game" location id *must* be `END`, all caps, three letters.
- Item and location ids are case sensitive and must match exactly between the two inputs to be considered the same item or location
- Each location can be reached only once, even if it is reachable from multiple sets of requirements
- You may assume that every location id on the locations list appears at least once on the rules list and that there is at least one `END` in the rules list
- You may assume that each location id on the locations list appears exactly once and contains exactly one item.
- There is no concept of one-way doors that block off access to previously accessible locations. The requirements list is unordered.
- Location ids and item ids are separate and distinct. For instance, `Morph` as a location is different from `Morph` as an item.
- Output a truthy value for a beatable seed and a falsy value for an unbeatable seed.

Happy golfing!

---

Sandbox: there's a lot here. Any suggestions for explaining things better? Should I add more test cases?

Comment: You might be interested in [Rado](https://github.com/alercah/rado), a language that's attempting to quickly(ish) solve this problem more generally.  I'm not related to the project in any way, I just think it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

## Break Hello World (Cops)/Fix Hello World (Robbers)

### Cops

Your job is to write a broken hello world program. What do I mean by that? Well, you write a valid hello world program, and make changes to it.

Your probably thinking "easy peasy", right? Well, there's one other condition: it must be hard to fix.

Anyways, for the actual rules. First you write a valid hello world program. That means:

- The characters sent to stdout form the string "Hello World!" exactly. Then the program halts gracefully (if given enough time and resources).
- Nothing is read from stdin or sent to stderr.
- No interacting with the operating system (i.e. no modifying files, randomness (unless it is pseudorandom and the seed is the same each run), internet, other commands, etc...)
- No using built-in or imported hashes or cryptographic primitives. If the program implements cryptographic primitives, that's fine though.
- Should work no matter how or on what platform it is run, assuming default options. The language it is written in should be reasonably cross platform and not cost money as well.

Now, make any changes you want to it. However, your score will be based on the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the valid and broken program (the lesser the better). The exact scoring will be described below.

The broken program can be any string you like (so calling it a "program" is technically a misnomer). Your submission will consist of:

- The broken program
- The edit distance between the valid and broken program, or any greater distance. (The reason you might want a greater distance is if the exact distance would reveal too much information. However, your score will suffer, and the robbers will have more flexibility, so be careful exercising this option). This number will be called your "brokenness" number.
- The language and language version of the valid program. This language should not be one written for this challenge.
- The sequence of literals appearing in the valid program, in the order they appear. (This is to encourage cops to scramble the program structure, not just hard coded values.)
- What the score will be if it is not cracked and after you reveal the solution.
- The date and time at which the program will be safe (as described below). (This way your program will be safe as soon as this time is reached, even if you have not had an opportunity to reveal the solution yet.) You may edit this in immediately after posting the solution, if you prefer, so that you will now the submission time.

After that, the robbers will have 168 hours (one week) to crack your submission from the date posted. If your submission is not cracked by then, your entry is safe. However, you can not claim your score until after you reveal the solution. To do this, edit your answer to include the valid program and an explanation as to why it works (if it takes a while to run). Also include what edits where made (since calculating the edit distance can be hard) and the word "safe" in the title.

How can your program be cracked? A robber just needs to write a valid hello world program (not necessarily the same as you wrote) whose edit distance from your broken program is less than or equal to your submission's brokenness number. The only other stipulation is that it has the same language and language version. In particular, it is not required to use the same literals as your program (this is to discourage cops from making their submission harder to crack this way).

And now for score. If the length of the broken program is L, the brokeness number is b, and the number of characters that can be used in your programming language is k, your score is [`(k^b)*(L+b)!/(L!b!)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(k%5Eb%20(b%20%2B%20L)!)%2F(b!%20L!)%20where%20k%20%3D%20256.0,%20b%20%3D%207,%20L%20%3D%20100), which you are trying to minimize. If your wondering were the heck that formula came from, it is *very roughly* the number of strings whose edit distance from your broken program is less than or equal to your submission's brokenness number (the exact value is hard to compute) (NOTE TO SANDBOX READERS: If you know a more accurate metric that isn't too complicated, let me know.). The idea is that the smaller the search space the robbers have to search, the more impressive it is if it does not get cracked. Also, please post the score in scientific notation for easy comparison.

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), so the submission which claims the lowest score wins!

Example Answer:

Python 2.7, score 7.5×10^53 (Safe)
Broken Program: `salida "Hola Mundo!"`
Brokenness Number: 18
Literals: "Hello World"
Safe Date: Feburary 12th, 3:42 PM UTC.

Valid program: `print "Hello World!"`
Edits: Make 7 replacements to get to `saida "Holao dorld!"`. Make 4 deletions to get to `saida "Hola do!"`. Make 4 insertions to get to `salida "Hola Mundo!"`.
Explanation: Uses python's builtin `print` command to send `"Hello World!" to standard output.

### Robbers

Welp, the cops did it again. They broke some hello world programs. Its your job to fix them.

Your probably thinking "easy peasy, I'll just rewrite it from scratch", right? Well, there's one other condition: you have a limited number of edits.

Anyways, for the actual rules. Pick a submission from the cop's thread that has not already been cracked, and is not safe. A submission is safe if it is over 168 hours (one week) old. The submission will have a broken hello world program, a brokenness number, and a programming language and language version, as well as some other useful information (including what literals in the cop's valid hello world program). Your submission must contain a valid hello world program in that language and language version whose [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to the broken program is less than or equal to the brokenness number. See the cop thread for what constitutes a valid hello world program. Also note that you **are not** required to use the same literals the cop used. They are only meant to give you a hint.

Your robber submission should consist of:

- A link to the cop entry you are trying to break.
- Your valid hello world program.
- An explanation as to why it works (if it takes a while to run).
- The edits you made to create the program (since calculating edit distance can be hard).

and then place a comment in the cops submission with a link to your submission. You get a point for each submission cracked. Note that only the first robber to crack a given cop submission gets a point. If you post a submission cracking a cop's submission, but it turns out another robber posted one before you, edit your submission to say that it is non-competing (or you can delete it if you want to). It is also non-competing if you crack a submission that is already safe.

This is [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), so whichever robber gets the most points wins!

Comment: I don't think the requirement for solutions to include "The sequence of literals appearing in the valid program" is a great idea; in particular I suspect it would run into similar arguments over the definition of "literals" as we've previously had when challenges tried to regulate builtins, comments, strings, etc. Perhaps this won't end up that way, but I don't think it's worth the risk.

Comment: I basically understand what you were trying to do with the scoring formula, but I don't think using "number of characters that can be used in your programming language" is a good idea. For one thing, I'm pretty sure there are at least some languages where all unicode could validly appear somewhere in the source code. I think a formula that only uses `b` and `L` would be better. Since L is calculated in bytes, I think the most neutral change would be to just replace `k` with 256.

Comment: I also think it would be a good idea to put "also known as 'Levenshtein Distance'" next to your "edit distance" link, or even just use the term Levenshtein Distance instead. It's not a huge deal, but Levenshtein Distance seems to be the more common term in existing challenges (though "Levenshtein edit distance" seems to be a compromise with some precedent).

Comment: Your scoring system is weird and confusing. Why not have the cop score be the Levenshtein Distance and say the lowest scoring safe program wins?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Well, regarding literals, I'm not sure of a good way to encourage cops to scramble the program structure other than this and a popularity contest. Without that restriction, the challenge basically becomes "for what input does this program make it to the "print 'Hello World'". Also, yes, I think I'll make L and b be specified in bytes and k=256. And I'll edit Levenshtein Distance into the question.

Comment: @Beefster Then they came make the program as long as they want. They could either have a small "changeable" section, and make the rest of the program either raise an error or print hello world based on some NP-complete problem, or have a massive hello world program with only four or five errors.

Answer (score 0):

#### MisterGeeky's query-to-list challenges:

*<sup>**It is up to you whether you interpret these challenges as following a pattern.**</sup>*

---

***Challenge 1***:- Given an array of random numbers and a target number, sample pairs in the array whose sum is closest to the target.

<strike>Minimize the error function.</strike> To explain this challenge, I need elucidate on the random list.

`L = [8.76, 7.89, 6.98, 9.99]`

That's just a handmade random list. Yours can be auto-generated of any length.

Say `target = 42`.

Find a tuple made from cartesian LxL whose sum of elements is closest to target.

These are obviously not the best words to pose the challenge with, they will be refined. How close is this to golf?

Challenge 1.5:- Extend the above problem with all known operations, and even increase the number of numbers that can be taken at a time to reach the target.

`op = ['*', '**', '^', '/', '+', '-']`

Assume usual meaning for each, `**` is sometimes for exponentiation but you can use it for tetration, similar to knuth's up arrow notation. '^' is either XOR or exponentiation. You have the liberty to choose operators. I meant operators known to you in general. Just normal arithmetic should even do.

`op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']`

I also allow any binary function that doesn't trivially output the target value.

---

***Challenge 2***:- Find list of Adjacent Elements to a given element or element position in any 4-dimensional matrix. (ie, m rows* n columns * p sheets * 4th dim whatever)

Even I'm not sure how this is golf. But I typically like to think there's only one approach that's the correct answer. Feel free to argue with me on that :D
The idea is that this knowledge gives you a starting point to find n-neighbours of a cell location.

So, you typically have 8 directions of search (4 pure and 4 combined). 
You start with listing the immediate neighbours

Challenge 2.5:- Find specified number of adjacent elements of a point in n-space. You are free to either sample at random, use rank of the point or use minimum euclidean distances.

Here, you find n-neighbors of a given item. Points for creativity.

---

<strike>Challenge 3:- build a simple recommender, takes a query and outputs a list (recommender as a suggestions lister is not easily defineable)</strike>

Challenge 3.5:- improve recommendation efficiency (too advanced for golf)

Third challenge is anything that combines knowledge from first and second challenge.

...

The above are to be refined as golfing challenges, shortest code is the best code.

Please comment your thoughts below. Thanks.

Comment: *all known operations*, *adjacent*, *recommender*, *efficiency*? I'm missing some definitions here.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for using the sandbox! While this seems pretty clearly to be a work in progress, I don't think there is particularly much for readers to comment on at the moment. You might consider expanding the first idea into a more complete challenge first so you can receive more useful feedback. From the way the first challenge is worded, I think you may have some trouble with ensuring the error is sufficiently minimised if golf is the goal.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes, I aso think there are more eleqouent ways to pose the problem. I'm actually not sure what golf is. Is it heuristic shorthand? I'm slowly completing the challenge definitions. My aim is to also make them feel good to read, not just sound jibberish one can't relate with. So, your inputs would be most useful.

Comment: @Adám Um, I'll remember to do that, but I meant english words. Operation is assumed as binary input function yielding one result value. Adjacent is the direct nearest neighbours, left and right elements incase of a 1D list or array. There will be 8 adjacent elements for an element is a matrix and 26 adjacent elements for an element in a datacube. A recommender is a function that you assume can give you a list of suggestions based on an input-query or item selection. Efficiency is same as the time to get solution. I'll be more than happy to clarify further doubts.

Comment: I think I see what you mean by the first challenge now. Sorry about my language, I mean "golf" in the sense that the ultimate goal is code golf, that is, writing as short a program as possible. The first challenge appears fine in this regard now, but 1.5 will suffer from this the way you have it worded now. Since each competitor will want to minimise their code, they will implement as few operators as possible. You should certainly specify precisely which operators need to be supported.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I am yet to generalize to the maximum extent possible. Writing the question seems so much harder than actually answering it. Um, in 1.5, I mean to say replace the summation of tuples with any other operation to get near to target. I'd have liked to added more challenges along the lines of, you can sample more than two elements to get output, you can reuse but according to some limitation et cetera. These are not simple to pose, especially when this 1d/2d concept is supposed to analogize a higher dimensional thing.

Answer (score 0):

## Product and Sum free set

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Given some non-negative integer \$n\$ find a sum- and product-free subset \$S \subset \mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots \}\$ of size \$|S|=n\$

**EDIT:** with the least possible maximum \$\max_{s\in S} s\$.

#### Details

- A set \$S\$ is called sum-free if for all \$a,b\in S\$ their sum \$a+b \not \in S\$.
- A set \$S\$ is called product-free if for all \$a,b\in S\$ their product \$a\cdot b \not \in S\$.

[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84673/is-it-a-sum-free-set)

#### Examples

Note that the sets for each \$n\$ might not necessarily be unique.

```
  n  S
  1  {2}
  2  {2,3}
  3  {3,4,5}
  5  {4,5,6,7}
```

**EDIT:** Ok, no this doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that this would just be `output the first n odd primes`, but maybe non-golfing languages can do something more interesting than that.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks for the feedback, you're right this is not something I considered. Maybe it helps if we allow any number of additions/multiplications? But in this case I think you could just use `[k+1,k+2,k+3,...,n]` for some large enough `k` (depending on `n`). Maybe I should add some condition that requires the numbers to be very small to make it more interesting. It definitely needs some more work.

Comment: You can make this work by having a secondary scoring algorithm.  You could, for example, score the programs by {bytes}*{total score for n=1 to 100}, where the score for an input is the highest number in the output set.

Comment: Also note that the set {1} is not product free - 1*1=1, which is in {1}.

Answer (score 0):

## Reducing switches in a binary matrix

A row's switch count is the amount of times the array switches from `1 -> 0` or `0 -> 1` when reading the array sequentially. As a Python function this looks like:

```
def row_switch_count(row):
    switch_total = 0

    last_r = row[0]

    for rr in row[1:]:
        if last_r != rr:
            switch_total += 1

        last_r = rr

    return switch_total
```

A matrix's switch count is the maximum switch count of all it's rows:

```
def mat_switch_count(bin_mat):
    max_switch = 0

    for row in bin_mat:
        count = row_switch_count(row)

        if max_switch < count:
            max_switch = count

    return max_switch
```

Write a function to reduce a matrix's switch count for each row to be less than a desired toggle count by permuting the elements in the **n**th column. You should permute as few columns as possible.

### Permissible permutations

The only permutation allowed is moving the column. You can move a column's index, but you cannot mutate the column itself. For example, you cannot change a column `[1, 0, 0] -> [0, 0, 1]`. However, you can move a column within a matrix:

```
([1, 0, 0], ->  ([0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0])      [0, 0, 0])
```

### Input

A binary array with `rows > 1` and `cols > 5`. The sum of all rows in any given column less than 1.

A `desired_toggle_count >= rows`.

### Examples

Note the solutions are not unique and not all solutions need to be provided. However, there is guaranteed to be a solution, since the trivial solution where you sort all the columns, is valid.

```
desired_toggle_count=3
([1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,1,1]) 
=> 
([1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,1])

-----

desired_toggle_count=4
([1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,1,1])
=>
([1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0])

or

([1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]))

----

desired_toggle_count=4
([1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1])
=>
([1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0])

or

([1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0])

----

desired_toggle_count=5
([1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1])
=> 
([1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1])

----

desired_toggle_count=4
([1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
 [0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0])
=>
([1,0,1,0,0,1,1],
 [0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0])
```

### Sandbox comments

I think this question might have too many requirements to be interesting? Brevity is the soul of wit and this question is not very brief.

Comment: 1. I think the definitions are not standard enough to assume in the first paragraph, and the task would be much more readable if the definitions came before the task specification. 2. NumPy is rather cryptic: it's optimised for speed rather than legibility (especially to non-Python programmers), so it's not very effective as a communication format. 3. The output section should be about formatting, not processing. 4. What happened to "*n-dimensional*" from the first line?

Comment: 5. I've clearly not understood the definition of *toggle count*, because I think `([1,0,1,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,1,1,0])` from the second example has a toggle count of at least six. 6. Since each column has zero or one 1s, the Hamming distance constraint can be given without mentioning Hamming distance: the permitted operations are permuting the elements in the \$n\$th column, and you should permute as few columns as possible.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you for your feedback. I tried to address all of your suggestions. Please let me know if I can improve this puzzle further!

Comment: OK, I get it now. I'm still not convinced by the test cases: why isn't `([1,0,1,1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,1]) ` a strictly better solution for the first one? Also, it might be worth adding a guarantee that there will be a solution.

Comment: @PeterTaylor in your example, you've modified one of the columns, which isn't permitted. I've added example mutations. Sorry, I got confused, when you said "permutation".

Comment: I feel like the python code at the beginning is not particularly illuminating. I think the rest of your description is adequate, and I think you risk hiding more important details like the moving as few columns as possible. Speaking of, it is probably a good idea to state the number of columns moved in each solution. In fact, it may be a better idea to simply make that the output, as it will make other answers easier to verify and it capture what seems to be important.

Answer (score 0):

## (bit)Wise Images

Given a truth table and two images, use the truth table as a bitwise operation to the two images.

For example with the truth table:

```
  1 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

(Note that the top is the first image and the left is the second)

and the two images `(0, 2, 4)` (a `1x1` image, with the numbers being RGB values) and `(30, 20, 10)`:

You would apply the above truth table to the numbers `0` and `30`, of which's binary representations are `00000` and `11110`.
Using the truth table as a bitwise operation would get us `00000`, or in decimal form `0`.

This means that the red value of the first pixel would be `0`.

Continuing this with the other RGB values would get us `2` and `4` for green and blue respectively.

So the output for this would be a `1x1` image with the only pixel having an RGB value of `0, 2, 4`.

**NOTES:**

You can use any default input or output method.

You can assume that the two input images are the same dimensions.

You can support any image format you want as long as the image format supports RGB values from #000000 (0, 0, 0) to #ffffff (255, 255, 255).

The truth table can be in any format you want

Comment: Are the images guaranteed to be the same dimension? What image formats should be supported (or is it up to us?)? Are we generating a 3rd photo or overwriting the two existing ones (due to asymmetric truth tables, 1+2 can be different from 2+1)?

Comment: I think you should more clearly specify your value ranges. One would assume, your image channels contain eight bits of entropy.

Comment: @Veskah I think both _format_ and _overwriting_ are covered by default I/O.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I'll yield format. And a second reread shows it as the inputs being Source image + Modifier image, whereas I thought it was "do this to both" at first

Comment: @Veskah I am sorry, but I neither understand what you mean by _"I'll yield format."_ nor _"Modifier image"_.

Comment: @JonathanFrech The former is "Yeah, fair enough on format, you are correct", the latter is "Image order matters due to the possibly asymmetric truth tables. So you can say the 1st image is the source and the 2nd image is the modifier which will result in the 3rd output image."

Comment: @Veskah Edited.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Sorry, but what do you mean by "image channels"

Comment: @MilkyWay90 _with the numbers being RGB values_ -- I mean the image's three color channels. In what value range do they live?

Comment: @JonathanFrech From 0 (0x00) to 255 (0xff)

Answer (score 0):

## Perfectly stable code

You are a.... Let's say *prepared*, programmer. You are working on the code to end all code, and it must be perfectly stable. No crashes, memory corruptions, mispellings, or anything else must get in your way. Everything else was set, but to your horrer you discovered that you had not accounted for the possiblity that the *sun* could actually flip a bit in your code! Naturally, you must now account for this.

#### The objective: A hello world program that still works if a single char is changed.

Questions:

- Has this been asked?
- What kinds of limits should I impose to make it possible? Allow 10% of chars to  be safe, limit the charset to just ASCII, ect.
- Is it possible?

Comment: [This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/write-a-program-that-always-outputs-2012-even-if-its-modified) is similar.

Comment: [Of course it's possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/180257/39244)

Comment: In fact, it's solvable [rather trivially](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/introducing-funkiller) in certain languages.

Comment: Would it be sufficiently different if I didn't have the requirement that the modification is syntactically valid?

Comment: Of course. But that would probably heavily restrict the possible language set, as seen in the other linked challenge

Comment: The tag you're looking for is [tag:radiation-hardened], though most challenges deal with *deletion* rather than *modification*. I would strongly recommend using bytes rather than characters. In fact, if you want to make it more interesting and closer to the original premise (as well as a little easier), how about using changing bits instead? You should also add a winning criteria (I assume [tag:code-golf]) and specify the exact output of (`Hello, World!`)

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games)[time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)

## Centurion Counter

The drinking game Centurion is extremely simple - 1 shot of alcohol (usually beer or cider) once a minute for 100 minutes.

Whilst playing the other day a friend commented that we didn't need the tracking app, and that we could have just written the program ourselves. So now it is your turn.

## Task

Write a program that once every 60 seconds produces a beep or sound to alert players a minute has passed, and then add one to the counter of how many shots have been had.

The counter starts at 1 (the first shot) and then ends at 100 when the last counter is taken.

Comment: What's the winning criterion here? code-golf?

Comment: Aside from choosing a winning criterion, I think you need to be more explicit about what counts as a sound, or on what hardware this should work on. However, this is extremely similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/151772/31625) challenge as it is, so you might consider changing up what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a "l337 5P34K" challenge, or I have not yet found one. How about it? Simple string manipulation so it should fall under "C0D3 60LF", right? I.E, Leet speak encoder (challenge one), and leet speak decoder (challenge two).

Comment: You'll need to define the question a *lot* better than this. i.e. What substitutions define leet speak? If the challenge winning criteria is shortest program size, than [tag:code-golf] is correct. The string part would be probably be tagged [tag:substitution] . The closest I could find was the [tag:code-challenge] [Leet to English](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28789/76162)

Comment: As you've found a translator, I'll think about an encoder challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Plot an NACA Airfoil

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

[NACA airfoils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) are described using a series of digits that represent the miscellaneous properties of the airfoil profile.

The purpose of this challenge is to receive an airfoil number as input, and plot the profile of the airfoil.

### Background information:

4-digit NACA airfoils are generally described by their string `NACA ABCC`, where `A,B` are single digit integers, and `CC` is a 2-digit integer.

- `A` is the maximum camber as a percentage of the chord length.  Eg. `A=2` means that the camber is 2% of the chord length.
- `B` is the location (divided by 10) of maximum camber as a percentage of the chord length.  Eg. `B=4` means that point of maximum camber is 40% down the length of the chord.
- `CC` is the profile thickness as a percentage of the chord width. Eg. `CC=12` means that the width of the airfoil is 12% of the maximum chord length.

Using the example given above, `NACA2412`, a suitable profile plot would look something like this:
[image: NACA 2412 and NACA 0012]

Note that in the image above, the Red line is the camber line and the purple is representative of the symmetrical airfoil `NACA 0012`.

Any airfoils with a representative number of `NACA 00XX` are symmetrical in nature because they possess zero camber.

Possible scoring criteria are [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

*Any feedback is welcome.  I also plan on having more challenges for the 5-digit and 6-digit profiles.  Eventually, I will add equations to this post too.*

Another way this challenge could be run would be to have the programmer return a series of points around the profile.  This could be judged both for accuracy and quantity of points returned.  If this approach is used, this would probably be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with [tag:popularity-contest]? I highly recommend against using it unless you really know what you're doing, most of such challenges are closed as too broad ([tag:popularity-contest] isn't a broadness waiver). On the other hand, [tag:code-golf] is the most common winning criterion around here, so I highly recommend it. There are other issues, however, which make the challenge unclear. For example, what constitutes a valid plot image (including how axes, lines, areas and points can be represented)? How would the answer be judged on its accuracy? If the winning...

Comment: ... criterion isn't just code golf, then I recommend using the [tag:code-challenge] tag, since [tag:code-golf] implies a pure golfing competition.

Comment: There are well-defined equations relating the `x` and `y` coordinates, so perhaps submissions could return a set of `(x,y)` points, and they could be judged by how closely the entire set of points follows the profile lines?

Comment: The spec is completely opaque to me. It should be written without assuming any aerofoil-specific knowledge, not as a refresher for someone who already knew it but may have forgotten.

Comment: I think your idea is good, but the details are pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

## Optimize the JSON (WIP)

Consider function `f` which takes two objects `data` and `default`, and merge anything from `default` into `data` if `data` contains no such element. Take the two objects(if the one in your language can handle the required elements) or JSON as input, output a shortest JSON that, when given as `data`, output the same object as the original `data` do, as long as `default` doesn't change.

Comment: If posted as it is now, I would flag it: closed as unclear what you're asking

Comment: @Beefster That's what WIP means

Comment: I really have no idea what this challenge is. The title suggests making a representation smaller while the text seems to indicate some sort of merging process that really needs to be fleshed out.

Comment: add some examples!

Comment: @zevee Actually I don't know what I want on some situations, so this will be here for long time

Answer (score 0):

## Draw these shapes

Given: a width, a height, and a set of sets of points. Output: An image where each set of points is connected and colored in (like a shape). Each shape *must* be a different color from all of the other shapes, but the difference doesn't matter. The shapes must be in order; whether you start at the end or the beginning of the set doesn't matter, though.

### Examples

```js
//the code here has nothing to do with the actual challenge and just shows examples

document.getElementById("one").getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
const ctx = document.getElementById("two").getContext("2d")
ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,0);ctx.lineTo(0,300);ctx.lineTo(300,0);ctx.closePath();ctx.fill()
ctx.fillStyle = "lime"
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(200,0);ctx.lineTo(600,0);ctx.lineTo(300,300);ctx.closePath();ctx.fill()
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px dotted black}
```

```html
<pre>Width: 500, Height: 500, Set: [[[0, 0], [0, 300], [300, 300], [300, 0]]]</pre>
<canvas id="one" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<pre>Width: 600, Height: 300, Set:
[
  [[0,0], [0,300], [300,0]],
  [[200,0], [600,0], [300,300]]
]</pre>
<canvas id="two" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Scoring is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: is there any rules about how long I have to wait before posting to the main site?

Comment: It's usually best to wait at least 72 hours before going from the Sandbox to main. As for the actual challenge: do the colors need to be visually difference, or is changing a color from #FFFFFF to #FFFFFE enough difference (I assume the second, but if not, please explain how much different the colors have to be)? Also, is the input order of the points for the shapes important, where the last is always in front of the first? Or are we also allowed to have the green triangle behind the black one in your second example?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen any difference is enough. Order can be either descending or ascending, but must go sequentially. I'll add those to the question

Comment: You may want to add something about jpegs and other lossy image formats, and whether they are allowed. Also I think you should explain "in order" a bit more: do you mean later shapes will be drawn over earlier shapes (or vice versa)?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman. In order means later shapes will be drawn over earlier shapes or vice versa, that's why I said "whether you start at the beginning or the end of the set doesn't matter though." Also, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges says stuff about lossy formats (`Programs may output via a common raster graphics image format`)

Comment: What are the width and height?

Comment: the width and height of the outputted image. BTW, I've posted this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182104/draw-these-shapes (only need one more re-open vote)

Answer (score 0):

## Patch one line

> First question I've written, feedback is highly appreciated. If you can think of a clever title, I'll take that too.

---

### Challenge

In an effort to prove to your employer that Git commit count is a worthless metric, you've decided to break up all your changes from now on line by line.

Golf a program which can edit a patch file to remove all changed lines *except for one*.

### Patch file format

The patch file will be given by Git in the [unified diff format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format), although git will append multiple file changes together:

```
diff --git a/afile b/afile
index bf70e9e..d2df230 100644
--- a/afile
+++ b/afile
@@ -1,8 +1,9 @@
-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
+Lorem IPSUM dolor sit amet,
+++ (good luck parsing this line)
 consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Duis est elit, imperdiet ac dolor quis,
    volutpat commodo nunc.
diff --git a/bfile b/bfile
index c484b2b..db4afe5 100644
--- a/bfile
+++ b/bfile
@@ -1,11 +1,7 @@
-#
-# /etc/bash.bashrc
-#
-
 # If not running interactively, don't do anything
 [[ $- != *i* ]] && return
 
 [[ $DISPLAY ]] && shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Here are two accepted outputs for the above patch file:

```
diff --git a/afile b/afile
index bf70e9e..d2df230 100644
--- a/afile
+++ b/afile
@@ -1,8 +1,9 @@
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
+++ (good luck parsing this line)
 consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Duis est elit, imperdiet ac dolor quis,
    volutpat commodo nunc.
```

```
diff --git a/afile b/afile
index bf70e9e..d2df230 100644
--- a/afile
+++ b/afile
@@ -1,8 +1,9 @@
-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Duis est elit, imperdiet ac dolor quis,
    volutpat commodo nunc.
diff --git a/bfile b/bfile
index c484b2b..db4afe5 100644
--- a/bfile
+++ b/bfile
@@ -1,11 +1,7 @@
 #
 # /etc/bash.bashrc
 #
 
 # If not running interactively, don't do anything
 [[ $- != *i* ]] && return
 
 [[ $DISPLAY ]] && shopt -s checkwinsize
```

#### Assumptions

> Any other corner cases I'm missing?

You do *not* need to handle the following cases:

- A file is deleted, renamed, or added
- A file has changed its mode

You *do* need to handle the following cases:

- An added line starts with `++`
- A removed line starts with `--`
- There are changes in multiple files (although you can remove one of the diffs and git will still patch okay)

### Input/Output

> Is this much explanation necessary?
>
> I added the stdin/stdout method since I imagine it's more conducive to golfing in some langs... Should I do any kind of bonus/penalty?

Your program may either take the name of the patch file as its first parameter and do an in-place edit (this will let `GIT_EDITOR=/path/to/your/program git add -e` apply the patch), *or* read from stdin and write to stdout such that the following will correctly apply the patch:

```
$ cat > oneline.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
mv "$1" "$1.old"
/path/to/your/program < "$1.old" > "$1"
EOF
$ chmod +x oneline.sh; GIT_EDITOR=./oneline.sh git add -e
```

Refer to the EDITING PATCHES section of [`man git-add`](https://manpage.me/?q=git-add) for some helpful info on editing the patch file.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

Answer (score 0):

## A Gödel numbering

### Task

In order to solve this challenge, you need to enumerate all possible programs in a turing-complete language given by you.

### Rules

- <strike>Either, you need to provide a function from a string-like type into a big-nat-like type, or you need to provide a program reading the program from STDIN and printing its Gödel number into STDOUT.</strike>
- Your function needs to be bijective, such that every different (as given by its behaviour) function gets mapped to a different natural number.

  - Example: If your turing-complete language is Brainfuck where I/O is the tape before/after the program ran, `+-` and `++--` may be mapped to the same number, since they both are no-ops.
- Your program must terminate for every possible input.
- Give a specification of your used language in the post or link it.
- This is a code golf (measuring in bytes).

Comment: Our I/O rules are usually a bit more relaxed (e.g. you can print from a function to STDOUT), there's no need to restrict them as that's not the core of the challenge.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well, that would actually be allowed, I'll still remove that rule

Comment: Yes, because "program" means "program or function", however that might not be the impression you'll give to everyone.

Comment: I think the word you are seeking is injective (modulo effect) rather than bijective.

Comment: If you allow for arbitrary languages, I can choose the language defined on \$\mathbb{N}\$ which executes the corresponding Turing machine using some Gödel numbering and submit the identity function as an answer to this challenge.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Slightly less arbitrary: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot

Comment: @JonathanFrech Injective with restrictions, yes. About the arbitrary language thing: I think this challenge is more about finding the right language, but I don't know how to imclude that in the score

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen This was actually in my mind when creating this cg

Answer (score 0):

## Mutual quine without sharing characters

Write a chain of at least 2 programs in different languages, that each program except the last one outputs the next, and the last program outputs the first. You may not reuse a character used in one program in any other programs.

Each language you use must have an entry in [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110648/25180).

Your score is the sum of the square of the best score in that challenge for each language you use. Highest score wins. Other users could challenge your score by posting better answers in that challenge.

---

Problems:

- Bytes / characters.
- How to define a proper quine for mutual quines? Without the restrictions specific to this challenge, someone will probably just print a string in most of the languages, and do all the encoding job in one most powerful language. But it might be not that relevant in this case, as that would most likely result in reusing characters.
- Scoring: sum(a<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup> - c), currently k=2 and c=0.
- Is this cops-and-robbers?

Comment: Ah oops, I actually did see that >.<. In that case [Mutually Exclusive Quines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153948/76162) in only one language

Comment: @JoKing In addition to scoring, it also requires different languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Word Calculator [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

This special calculator uses words instead of numbers, with these rules:

- Addition joins two or more strings together in the same order they were inputted.

Repeated letters (example: `aa`, `bb`, etc) in the output become a single letter. If there is more than one repetition, then this is performed only on the first such instance detected, when going in a left-to-right direction.

(eg: `tt` becomes `t`, `tttt` becomes `tt`, etc)

- `cat+dog+tiger = catdogtiger`
- `dog+cat+tiger = dogcatiger`
- `dog+cat+tiger+tuna = dogcatigertuna`
- `dog+cat+ttiger+tuna = dogcattigertuna`
- `dog+cat+tttiger+tuna = dogcattigertuna`

  (last example was originally `= dogcattttigertuna`, `tttt` is present but only the *first* repetition is removed, leading to the answer as shown)

---

- Subtraction follows the same rules as the addition, but with a twist. Addition proceeds as usual, but when a subtraction is encountered, this subtracts as many characters as that string from whatever the output would have been before the subtraction.

You will not be expected to handle negative values.

- `cat+dog-tiger = c`
- `cat+tiger-dog = cati`
- `cat+dog+ttiger-tuna = catdogt`
- `cat+dog+tttiger-tuna = catdogtt`
- `cat+dog+ttiger-tuna-salmon = c`
- `cat-dog = 0`

---

---

The shortest code in bytes that performs the above addition and subtraction functions as described, is the winner.

Standard loopholes are not allowed.

Comment: Does the reduction of even letters happen when the operation that caused the repeating letters finishes or at the end of the expression? Otherwise, seems like a pretty interesting challenge

Comment: I can't make any sense of "*Subtraction removes as many characters as the last string, to all strings combined except it, in the same order they were inputted.*" Reverse engineering from the examples, I think the definition is that subtraction removes a number of characters equal to the length of the subtrahend from the end of the minuend. An example showing the reduction of even repeats after subtraction would be nice: the current example actually shows reduction after addition before the subtraction is performed. The letter e might work for examples: bee ends in a double letter.

Comment: So non-positive results are literally "0", not the empty string or something? What happens if you try and add to that? (p.s you don't have to define every behaviour. you can just say "you won't get an input that causes this")

Comment: @JoKing Fixed. I hope I've included enough examples to clarify what the intention is. I've attempted to cover some stranger cases too to ensure that it's clearer and that there is less ambiguity surrounding what to do when. I generally don't expect negative or otherwise weird values to be handled, and I've added that.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: `This is performed only on the first such instance detected.` But on your example `dog+cat+tttiger+tuna = dogcattigertuna`, there was more than one reduction. Am I missing something?

Comment: `dog+cat+tttiger+tuna` would originally have been `dogcattttigertuna`, the repetitions are `tttt`, but only one is removed, leaving the other `tt` intact.

Comment: But it says they become a single letter

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Fixed now. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: So the amount of repeated letters is just original letters divided by two floored?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Whether you'd be doing that is up to your solution eventually, maybe that isn't the optimal golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Is the Art Gallery Fully Guarded? (WIP)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

---

The [Art Gallery Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem) is a well-studied visibility problem concerning the minimum number of guards that must be placed within a polygon. This challenge will explore a simplified grid-based decision-problem variant to make input and visibility checking simpler.

You will receive a grid of walls and floors as input, representing the layout of the art gallery, and a number of guards (either as a list of locations or another value in the grid input.) You must determine whether all floor tiles are visible by at least one guard and return a truthy value if so and a falsy value otherwise.

### Visibility

A floor tile is considered visible to a guard if the line connecting the center of the floor tile to the center of the tile containing the guard does not pass through any wall tiles. If this line passes through the corner of a wall tile, visibility is not obstructed. (*Sandbox: this can be an issue for floating point precision. Maybe a more discrete method should be used? Perhaps [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)?*) The tile a guard occupies is also visible to that guard.

### Examples

Key: `.` Floor, `#` Wall, `G` Guard

```
# . # G . .
. . # . . #
. . # # . .
# G . . . #
# # # . . #
. . . G # #

==> YES


. # . # # . . .
. # . . . . . #
. . . . . G . .
. . . . . . . .
. # . . . . . #
. # . # # . . .

==> NO
```

More TBD after visibility is hammered down

### Rules, Notes, Assumptions

- Standard challenge rules, IO methods, and loopholes apply
- Guards may be taken in either as a list of coordinates or embedded within the grid.
- You may assume that guards will always be standing on a floor tile
- You may assume that grids will always be perfect rectangles, not jagged arrays
- You may assume that grids will never be larger than \$100 \times 100\$

Happy Golfing!

Comment: About visibility, It's actually OK. Instead of using floating point, you use rational number.

Comment: And yes, I mean Bresenham's Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

## Calculator using only addition

Your task is to create a program or function that emulates a four-function calculator, capable of performing addition, subtraction, multiplication, and integer division. However, the catch is that your code must not use any mathematical operations other than addition. In other words, you must use only addition to implement the three other basic arithmetic operations.

### Input

Your program should take two numbers and an operation as parameters. Input can come in any form, whether it's through function parameters, standard input, etc. The operation can be represented however you want. You could use +, -, *, ÷, or `"add"`, `"subtract"`, `"multiply"`, `"divide"`, or whatever else is convenient. For division, you can assume that there will be no division by 0, and that the numbers will evenly divide.

### Output

Your program should output one number to STDOUT, the result of the calculation.

### Restriction

As mentioned earlier, you may not use any mathematical operation in your code other than the addition operator.

### Rules

- No mathematical operators other than addition, as specified above.
- Bitwise operations are not allowed, but logical and comparison operators are.
- Data type conversion is allowed.
- Negation using a built in is allowed (e.g. `-x` or `negate(x)` are both fine).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Sandbox

- Wouldn't surprise me if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find it. If it is, just put a link to the original in the comments please.
- The input section seems like it could use some work, but I don't know what to change about it.
- Other than that, let me know if there's anything that could be improved.

Comment: This would work far better if the only operation allowed was subtraction. Then it ultimately looks a lot like a [one-instruction computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer#Subtract_and_branch_if_less_than_or_equal_to_zero)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/655/multiply-without-multiply) - this challenge was closed. Do X without Y challenges are generally not well-received on this site.

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the order of a Rubik's Cube cycle without trivially counting them

See: [Compute the order of a Rubik's Cube cycle without trivially counting them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182709/compute-the-order-of-a-rubiks-cube-cycle-without-trivially-counting-them)

I asked this question here the other day and it was closed as being a duplicate of another question which I had already linked in the original question followed by an explanation of a constraint that made the my challenge different. A discussion ensued in the comment section debating what made my question a duplicate of the other, mostly revolving around whether this constraint was  [observable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/should-we-disallow-non-observable-requirements) or not.

I understand that the challenge at face value is an example of [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8079#8079) but I think it's still a quality challenge because:

1. The constraint does not simply exist to require people to come up with loopholes or clever workaround to preform avoid a particular commonly used feature of programming languages. It's not the same problem with an unrelated constraint to "make it interesting".
2. There really is no ambiguity in terms of whether or not the constraint is being followed for a particular answer. "Without Y" is not hard to define regardless of the language being used.
3. It changes entire approach needed for the algorithm itself, not just specifics of the implementation. The trivial solution to the question will automatically be preferred by golfers, so the answers of the "duplicate" were not very interesting to me because they mostly worked in the exact same way. By prohibiting this trivial approach, there is still a very wide range of different degrees of efficiency that are possible to achieve through different implementations, and some of these are likely better suited for some languages than others, so I feel the answers will actually show significant diversity in their implementations, which in my opinion is a hallmark of a high quality challenge.

I really think this constraint introduces a meaningfully different and interesting challenge when compared to the other question and I want to see the creative solutions that golfers will come up with to solve it. But as I originally wrote it, and even with the addition of edits I made to make it more clear, it was apparently not sufficient to reopen the question.

Can anyone think of a way to write this question or define the constraint in a way that would make it more clearly not a duplicate, or eliminate the problems brought up in the comments without restricting the implementation further?

Do you think I'm only facing this scrutiny because I'm a newer member who hasn't posted much? Would someone with more reputation that me be willing to post it on my behalf?

Comment: `There is no ambiguity`, Isn't there though? How would you tell that [this program](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0evtDRXryi81iMlxSG@ODfeSS/TLUDPLtk4Ktu4IsrDPb4oPqIqRj3G2NIvTbG4NigkOcqo0jZKKdTFJ8jN6f//oNAg9VB1AA) is following the constraint without actually knowing Pyth?

Comment: @JoKing that’s not ambiguity. For example if a challenge were to prohibit the use of the a built in to_lower() function (which I’ve seen before on challenges with plenty of answers and upvotes) how would you know if a given answer was obeying that rule without actually knowing what a call to that language’s to_lower() function looked like? You wouldn’t, but that answer would still break the rules. But it wouldn’t be “ambiguous” because there’s still a clear difference between using such a built in function and not using one.

Comment: Banning built-ins is also an unobservable requirement, and is common in older questions. In general, the community is leaning towards [avoiding banning built-ins](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/56656). In general though, programs using built-ins are far far easier to distinguish than whether a program is using a specific algorithm.

Comment: The point of what I'm saying is that a constraint being unobservable is entirely different from there being cases where it's ambiguous if it's being followed. Whether or not an algorithm is obeying my constraint I suppose could be difficult to know immediately for some answers, especially if you're unfamiliar with the language it's written in, but at the same time the constraint is still defined quite clearly. Nobody reasonable person could possibly write an answer and not be sure if it is following this rule or not. That's what I mean by there's no ambiguity.

Comment: It is ambiguous if two people can have different opinions on whether it is following the constraint. For example, what is a `simulated cube`? Is it a literal Rubik's cube datatype like Cubically uses? Does a 5x5x5 sided cube still count as a Rubik's cube? Does a list of numbers count? Two vectors? Non-cube topologies? I'm sure some answerers will have different opinions to yours, and even if you define all the above cases, there's going to be infinitely more possibilities that skirt the line.

Comment: @JoKing A simulated cube is any data structure(s) that represents the state of a 3x3x3 rubik's cube, and is manipulated to represent the changes caused by preforming valid turns. A simulated 5x5x5 Rubik's would be a simulated cube because you can turn a 5x5x5 into a 3x3x3 by just removing stickers (or in the case of a data structure, ignoring them). As for a list of numbers, or two vectors, etc, if the purpose is to of it is to represent the state of the cube, and it is manipulated to simulate preforming valid moves on it, it's a simulated cube. Do you still think this is ambiguous?

Comment: @JoKing Can you think of an example of an algorithm where you feel there could be reasonable, legitimate debate, as to whether or not it counts as "Performing the turns repeatedly on a simulated cube and counting the repetitions that were needed to reach the original state"?

Comment: Maybe the challenge could be for an N*N*N cube with N as an input? Then, some limit on complexity or run-time should be able to weed out programs that just iterate through the cycle.

Comment: In the context of this site, we generally use "observable" to mean observable without looking at the code. So even if there's a strong argument that a constraint could be determined unambiguously, it's still a quality of the code, rather than of the output. I'm not aware of an outright rule against this, but it is generally advised against because it leads to unexpected arguments once the answers start coming in. The exceptions that are more likely to be welcomed are the trivial constraints like "source code is a palindrome" or "does not contain the letter e"

Comment: Personally I'd lean away from even those as they tend to suit a smaller set of languages. So there isn't a rule preventing you placing constraints on the source code, but it makes it more likely your challenge will be closed as unclear, so it might be worth considering what alternatives might achieve your underlying aim without the risk of arguments over what counts.

Comment: For example, some challenges exclude the simplest brute force approaches by saying "must complete within 60 seconds for each of the test cases" (the time period being chosen to be very easily achievable for most approaches, so that it doesn't even matter what machine is used to measure the time taken). That's still not perfect but seems to have worked well on several past challenges.

Comment: I can't think of a similar way of achieving your stated constraint without explicitly including it in the spec, but I thought I'd mention this example in case it prompts someone to think of a similar approach that could work here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use input letters to create as many words as possible

---

I have the scrabble letters as magnets on my fridge and I was thinking: how many actual words could I make using only these letters. Obviously it would be hard to work out myself, so I challenge you to create a program which will take a string of characters as input, and your goal is to output as many words as possible using those characters.

#### Input

- The characters will be one string
- Only the 26 letters of the alphabet will appear.
- Letters may appear more than once
- Letters can appear in any order. 5 e's might appear next to each other, and there might be other e's in the string.
- There will always be at least a single letter, but it might not always be possible to create a valid word

Example, using the letters from Scrabble:

> eeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiioooooooonnnnnnrrrrrrttttttllllssssuuuuddddgggbbccmmppffhhvvwwyykjxqz

#### Output

A list of valid English words, which you can separate with a space, newline or comma. A trailing newline at the end is fine.

[Default loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word)[natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

---

#### Meta discussion (not apart of the question)

- Is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) a decent challenge for this? I'm more interested in more words being output than I am short code, but how best can I frame this challenge that the best result would be most words created and fewest characters left?
- Should I restrict the input list to *just* the letters from Scrabble? I mean how can I evaluate whether a program prints as many as possible?
- Should I provide a word list? I know there are challenges on this site where a word list is provided [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/is-this-even-a-word) and [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133564/count-to-20-with-words) and I'm sure there are a few others which I could not find.
- This is my third question, so any other feedback

Comment: I would highly recommend including the wordlist as an input and including a few trivial test cases so that people can easily test their answers.

Comment: Not including the word list as input would benefit languages which have dictionary built-ins - everyone else would have to have a list of all English words in the code, which might be a little long, even given really good compression...

Comment: Allow any reasonable output format rather than just text. Pass in word lists and letter sets as arguments. Making both constant turns this into a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Who's serving in table tennis?

Table tennis, also known as ping pong, is a well-known game in which players hit a ball back and forth across a table. One player serves the ball twice, and each time the ball is served, either player can score a point. Once the first player serves the ball twice, the second player gets to serve twice. Every two serves, the player which serves the ball switches. The game ends when one player has a score of 11 or more points and is two or more points higher than the other player.

Your task is to take the current score as input, and output a value depending on if player 1 should serve, player 2 should serve, or the game is over.

Input: The score of the first player to serve followed by the score of the other player. This can be as separate values or in a list, or another convenient data type.

Output: A distinct value for each possible case of output. For the test cases, I will use `1` to represent the player who serves first, `2` to represent the other player, and `0` to represent that the game is over.

**Test cases:**

```
player1score, player2score -> output

2, 0    ->  2
0, 0    ->  1
11, 0   ->  0
4, 4    ->  1
3, 2    ->  1
6, 9    ->  2
81, 82  ->  2
0, 29   ->  0
16, 13  ->  0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Print the Golfican sequence

---

The Golfican sequence is a sequence of integers, \$u\$, defined as follows:

- If \$n\$ is a power of \$2\$, then \$u_n=\log_2n+1\$.
- If \$n\$ in *not* a power of \$2\$, then \$u_n=u_p\$, where \$p\$ is the number of numbers from \$1\$ to \$n\$ inclusive which are not powers of \$2\$.

So, the first numbers in this sequence are \$1,2,1,3,2,1,3,4\$ and so on. Your job is to write a program which takes a number, \$x\$, as input, and outputs \$u_x\$. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

---

I couldn't find a corresponding OEIS sequence for this. Thoughts?

Comment: So \$p = n - 1 - \lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor = n - u_{b(n)} = n - \ell(n)\$ where \$b(n)\$ is the largest power of 2 less than \$n\$ and \$\ell(n)\$ is the length of \$n\$ in base 2?

Comment: I suppose it would be.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternating Digit Divisibility

*TODO: Could use a better title..*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

### Challenge:

Given a list of at least two positive integers, output a pair of lists of digits. Both inner lists in the output are the digits which evenly divide each number in the alternating converted lists. The first converted list will be `[sum(digits(n)), n, sum(digits(n)), ...]`, and the second will be `[n, sum(digits(n)), n, ...]`.

**Step-by-step example:**

Input: `[611,44,381]`

Step 1: Convert it to the two alternating lists:

```
[[sum([6,1,1]),44,sum([3,8,1])],    →    [[8,44,12],
 [611,sum([4,4]),381]]                    [611,8,381]]
```

Step 2: Check for each number which digits evenly divides it:

```
[[[1,2,4,8],[1,2,4],[1,2,3,4,6]],
 [[1],[1,2,4],[1,3]]]
```

Step 3: Leave the digits present in each of the inner lists of lists, which is our output:

```
[[1,2,4],
 [1]]
```

Output: `[[1,2,4],[1]]`

### Challenge rules:

- I/O is flexible. Input can be a list of strings, integers, 2D list of digits, etc. Output can be a list of lists of digits, a single flattened list of digits (i.e. `[1,2,4,1]` in the example above), two lists printed on separated lines, each digit printed separated, a string or single (big) integer (i.e. `1241`), etc. etc.
- You're allowed to swap the order of the alternation if it's convenient in your language of choice (i.e. the example above would output `[[1],[1,2,4]]`/`[1,1,2,4]`/`1124`/etc. instead).
- `0` will never be in the output.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input:                      Output:

[611,044,381]               [[1,2,4]], [1]]
[200,32000,4000]            [[1,2], [1,5]]
```

*TODO: More to come, including some larger ones*

Comment: Isn't it two challenges in one? The alternating digits lists and then extracting common divisors of two lists?

Answer (score 0):

## Help the library sort books

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

A library needs to sort its books, located in separate sections by language. Of course, each language has its own rule for collating strings, so your method should handle that ability.

Most languages will want to treat titles case-insensitively, but unfortunately, the library has a section of Klingon books. And Klingon's romanisation, in case you don't already know, is case-sensitive. As a result, you need to give a way to have the sorter treat two given characters as the same.

Some of the titles also contain numbers, and you need to deal with those as well. Fortunately, the friendly people at the library have written some functions for you to deal with that, so all you have to do is take in a handle to a function as one of your inputs.

**Your challenge:** Sort a list of book titles, given a collating sequence and a function handle that converts a number to its string representation in the respective language.

- The collating sequence is a list of lists of strings. Given two strings *A* and *B* that appear respectively in the entries at indices *i* and *j*, respectively:

  - if *i* > *j*, then *A* should sort after *B*
  - if *i* = *j*, then *A* should sort the same as *B*
- In case some elements of the sequence have multiple characters, use the max-munch rule to tokenise the string: e.g. if both `l` and `ll` appear in the collating sequence, then `lll` should be tokenised to `ll l`.
- Any string of digits should be parsed as a number and passed to the callback. Each such string should be replaced by the result.
- Any characters not appearing in the collating sequence should be ignored. If two strings differ only by such characters, then sort them however you like.

### Test cases

Assuming

```
english_letters = [["A", "a"], ["B", "b"], ["C", "c"], ["D", "d"], ["E", "e"], ["F", "f"], ["G", "g"], ["H", "h"], ["I", "i"], ["J", "j"], ["K", "k"], ["L", "l"], ["M", "m"], ["N", "n"], ["O", "o"], ["P", "p"], ["Q", "q"], ["R", "r"], ["S", "s"], ["T", "t"], ["U", "u"], ["V", "v"], ["W", "w"], ["X", "x"], ["Y", "y"], ["Z", "z"]]
arka_letters = [["t"], ["k"], ["x"], ["s"], ["n"], ["v"], ["f"], ["m"], ["d"], ["g"], ["p"], ["b"], ["h"], ["y"], ["c"], ["r"], ["z"], ["j"], ["w"], ["l"]]
function english_num_callback(num) {
  // convert a number to its representation in English
}
function arka_num_callback(num) { // handles nonnegative integers up to 9999
  if (num == 0) return "yuu";
  let kot = 0 | (num / 1000);
  let gal = 0 | (num / 100 % 10);
  let on = 0 | (num / 10 % 10);
  let ko = num % 10;
  let digits = ["yuu", "ko", "ta", "vi", "val", "lin", "kis", "nol", "ten", "los"];
  return (kot == 0 ? "" : digits[kot] + "kot") +
    (gal == 0 ? "" : digits[gal] + "gal") +
    (on == 0 ? "" : digits[on] + "on") +
    (ko == 0 ? "" : digits[ko]);
}
```

```
["Stack Exchange", "BB94 Channel!", "BB guns: all you wanted to know about them",
  "carrots", "A Grammar of Jbl", "69"], english_letters, english_num_callback =>
  ["A Grammar of Jbl", "BB guns: all you wanted to know about them", "BB94 Channel!",
    "carrots", "69", "Stack Exchange"]
["melidia", "diaklel", "44 miiko", "I Mess With the Librarians", "an isk ris tu lei",
  "lei e xion", "xagrisren et xep!", "on melkadren"], arka_letters, arka_num_callback =>
  ["xagrisren et xep!", "44 miiko", "melidia", "diaklel", "lei e xion",
    "an isk ris tu lei", "on melkadren", "I Mess With the Librarians"]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Will it be red sauce, brown sauce, or no sauce at all?

Unfortunately Danny Baker's Sausage Sandwich game has been taken off the air again, and I'm suffering from withdrawal already. Please alleviate my symptoms by writing a program or function to play the Sausage Sandwich game.

You need to guess how the target prefers to eat a sausage sandwich, given one of the three sauce options. Given an input positive integer `n`, then the following applies:

- There is a uniformly [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) 1 in `n` chance that the target chooses no sauce at all.
- Otherwise, there are equal chances of red sauce or brown sauce.
- However, if `n` is even, then there are `n-1` remaining chances, which don't divide by 2. If you draw this `n-1`th chance you should consistently (for a given `n`) output the same answer. Please indicate how this is chosen in your answer.
- Output must consist of the phrases "red sauce", "brown sauce", or "no sauce at all", in any of lower, sentence, title or upper case.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185852/sliding-retrieval)

Comment: (1) IMO the multiple-box requirement is essential to make it an interesting question. Otherwise it's just the hundredth shortest path question, and probably should be closed as a dupe. (2) "*If your solution can only retrieve the first box, 10x penalty*" is a really bad idea. See [Things to avoid when writing challenges: chameleon questions](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/194), [bonuses in code golf](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks, I've removed the bonuses and outlawed brute force.

Comment: Banning brute force is also discouraged, as a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20283). Some people use a time limit to rule out the slowest kinds of brute force instead. For example, must process any of the test cases in under 1 minute (the time limit being chosen generous enough to make no difference to most approaches, so it doesn't even matter which computer it's measured on)

Comment: @trichoplax: I've modified to replace the brute force note with a time limit

Answer (score 0):

## Optimize Grocery Bagging

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

---

You've gone to the store and are at the checkout. Now since you want to be environmentally conscious (or are somewhere that charges for bags and want to save money), you've brought a few reusable bags and would like to minimize the number of plastic bags you use (There are no paper bags here).

Each reusable bag can carry 5 kg (5,000 grams) of groceries and each plastic bag can carry 2.5 kg (2,500 grams) of groceries. You will be given a list of weights of groceries (in whole grams) and a number of reusable bags and your task is to output a configuration of bagging that requires the fewest number of plastic bags.

### Examples

- **Input**: 1 reusable bag, groceries: [150, 500, 800, 1250, 2000, 300, 550, 400, 750, 900, 1000, 600]

  - **Output**: Reusable[2000, 1250, 1000, 750], Plastic[600, 900, 550, 150, 300], Plastic[500, 800, 400]

More TBD

### Rules and Assumptions

- Standard rules and loopholes apply
- Any convenient input or output method is acceptable as long as which bags are reusable is unambiguous in the output (without calculating anything).
- You may assume that there are no groceries larger than 2.5 kg. (No jugs of milk)
- All groceries listed require a bag. Unbaggable groceries will not be listed. (No hypothetical 24-packs of toilet paper)
- Any grocery item can be bagged with any other. (No need to worry about bread and cans of beans being in the same bag)
- Groceries cannot be split into multiple bags.
- There is no double-bagging.
- Complexity doesn't matter. There may be inputs that would require computation past the heat death of the universe to complete.

Happy Golfing!

---

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51468/45613)

*Sandbox*: This could work as a [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) problem or [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) due to the naive solution being in \$O(n!)\$. Thoughts?

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109797/25180

Comment: This is NP-hard.

Comment: @jimmy23013 yes, indeed. If this were shifted to [tag:fastest-code] it would necessarily drop the "guaranteed optimality" requirement.

Comment: @jimmy23013 I guess this is only different from that linked challenge in that there are two bag capacities instead of just one.

Comment: Do you mean requiring the minimum number of bags? If not required optimal, how do you decide whether an answer is valid?

Comment: As I remembered (USACO fence8), fast solutions to this problem may use strategies depending on the input data (e.g. try putting heavier things in bags first). You may have to specify exactly how it is scored if you change it to [tag:fastest-code].

Answer (score 0):

## Beziér me a curve!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Task:** Create a program that will, given a number *N*, create a Beziér curve with *N* control points and output its equation.

The definition of a Beziér curve is
$$
B(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n{{n\choose i}(1-t)^{n-i}t^iP_i}
$$

Practically, this means that for a quadratic Beziér cuve:
$$
B(2) = \sum_{i=0}^2{{2\choose i}(1-t)^{2-i}t^iP_i}\\
B(2) = {2\choose 0}(1-t)^2P_0 + {2\choose 1}(1-t)tP_1 + {2\choose 2}t^2P_2\\
B(2) = (t^2-2t+1)P_0 + 2(t^2-2t+1)P_1 + t^2P_2\\
B(2) = P_0t^2-2P_0t+P_0 + 2P_1t^2-4P_1t+2P_1 + P_2t^2
$$

where \$P_0\$ is the first control point, \$P_1\$ is the second control point and \$P_2\$ is the third control point.

Note that De Casteljau's algorithm may be useful.

### Rules

- The input will be a number (string or number).
- The output will be a list of lists. Take an element \$l_n\$ of the top-level list. The elements of \$l_n\$ will be all the terms that, in the expanded form, are multiplied by \$P_n\$. `-1t` and `t^1`, as well as `t^0` are all fine.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

### Test cases

`2`:

```
[
  ["t^2", "-2t", "1"],
  ["2t^2", "-4t", "2"],
  ["t^2"]
]
```

`5`:

```
[
  ["-t^5", "5t^4", "-10t^3", "10t^2", "-5t", "1"],
  ["t^5", "-4t^4", "6t^3", "-4t^2", "t"],
  ["t^5", "2t^4", "t^3"],
  ["-t^5", "t^4"],
  ["t^5"]
]
```

The program with the shortest length wins. Be creative!

Comment: It would be more accurate (and IMO less confusing) to say that the task is to output the Bernstein basis polynomials of degree n, $$b_{a,n}(t) = \sum_{k=a}^n (-1)^{a+k} \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{a} t^k$$ In line with [Avoid cumbersome I/O formats](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/194) I would also suggest outputting the polynomials as lists of coefficients, i.e. as a double array / matrix with $$A_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j} \binom{n}{i,j}$$. However, all of this is moot because now that I've rewritten it like that I see it's a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69424/194

Answer (score 0):

## [Proving that a Russian cryptographic standard is too structured](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186498/proving-that-a-russian-cryptographic-standard-is-too-structured)

Comment: Nice challenge. I have some suggestions for usability for solvers. Please say what language your example code is in (C?), and an online runnable version -- the community standard is [TIO](https://tio.run/#) which is maintained by a site mod ([example in Python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQakktbhE6f9/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")). A pseudocode version or explanation would also be appreciated. It would be useful to include a listing of the permutation as 256 numbers from 0 to 255 written in base 10. The references would be cleaner as inline hyperlinks.

Comment: You should allow submissions to be programs or functions, which [is default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet). Also, please change the scoring to bytes. I sympathize with wanting a fair comparison for 7-bit vs 8-bit languages, but past efforts have [proved unpopular](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11164/20260), and people now generally think of competitions as being within each language. You can leave the conversion to bits for your personal leaderboard.

Comment: Also, please make the challenge as self-contained as possible, which means putting into the challenge body the parts of the linked papers that are important for solvers. Here, I think this is mainly how the function `p` works. In particular, what does it mean that the table `k` is an affine function, and how can it be implemented as such? Does `s` have any structure?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I have updated the challenge and did my best to take them into account. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the edits. Now that you've explained that the core of the code is discrete log, I have some questions on that which other solver might have too. I take it the char declaration is to limit the values to 8 bits and discard bits? If I think of the field of size 256 as GF_2[X] modulo a certain irreducible polynomial, does the update `a=(a<<1)^(a>>7)*29` correspond to multiplying by a polynomial? Could the initialization be `l=0, a=1` instead? Note that LaTeX is enabled here, in case it's easier to write formulas. It also could help to say that `^` is xor, not power.

Comment: The answer to your questions are yes---mostly. The unsigned char are indeed used to discard some bits. We could alternatively replace `a=(a<<1)^(a>>7)*29` with `a=(a<<1)^(a>>7)*285` (where `256^29==285`, in which case we wouldn't need the unsigned chars. This code snippet indeed corresponds to a multiplication by a polynomial. However, we cannot start at `l=0,a=1`. For some reason, the designers of $\pi$ used a variant of the logarithm such that $\log_2(1)=255$ instead of $\log_2(1)=0$. Both are "correct" in the sense that $\alpha^{255} = \alpha^{0} = 1$ but this variant is less common.

Comment: I added these clarifications to the challenge.

Comment: The output of your C code seems to not match the table.

Comment: The table was wrong rather than the C code. Thanks for catching it! I fixed it as well as the corresponding TIO link. To further simplify the verification, I added a link to the wikipedia page of Kuznyechik which contains the table of the function `p`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94618/discussion-between-xnor-and-picarresursix).

Answer (score 0):

### Is this set doubly orderable?

For input you are given a set of four or five sets of strings. Each string is at least two characters long; those first two characters are always digits but the remaining characters can also be letters.

The set of sets is doubly orderable if an ordered list can be constructed using one element from each member of the set such that:

- The first characters of each element of the list are in nondescending order
- The second characters of each element of the list are separately in nondescending order
- If any elements of the list have more then two characters, then those elements are all wholly equal with each other and appear at the beginning of the list (while still satisfying the other conditions).

Although there is an ordering on the list itself, the original sets can be sampled in any order necessary to achieve a valid list.

Example valid lists:

```
13  24  25  36
13e 13e 13  13
33s 37  37  37
```

Example invalid lists:

```
13  33  15  35  (first character not in order)
13  15  33  35  (second character not in order)
13e 24s 25  36  (different overlong strings)
33  37s 37s 37s (overlong strings are not first)
```

For output you should have:

- A consistent value indicating that the set is not doubly orderable
- A consistent value indicating that the set is can be doubly ordered using only 2-character strings
- A list of all overlong strings of which one is needed to make a valid list.

Full example:

```
1. 13 23 33 14 24 34 15 25 35 16 26 36 17 27 37
2. 33s 15e 16 17e
3. 34 25
4. 17e 37
```

In this example the `34` and `25` in set 3 force us to use either `33s` or `15e` from set 2 and therefore the `37` from set 4, with a number of options from set 1. Since all the valid lists begin with either `33s` or `15e`, these are the outputs.

Comment: I find this spec quite confusing. (1) ISTM that the property "doubly ordered" should really be "doubly order**able**". (2) The order of the elements in the list can be inferred to be arbitrary from the fact that the spec talks about a *set* of sets, but it would be much better to make this explicit. E.g. change the second paragraph to start "*The set of sets is doubly orderable if a list can be constructed by taking one element from each member of the set and ordering them so that:*". (3) On the third bullet, do the elements have to be equal or just the suffixes?

Comment: @PeterTaylor (3) Yes, the elements have to be wholly equal in this case.

Answer (score 0):

## Reading the text of the millitext font

There is a font [here](http://www.msarnoff.org/millitext/) that fits each character into a single, 1x5 pixel block. It does this (assuming you're using an LCD screen) by using the RGB channels of each pixel to expand the one pixel into three subcolumns, one for each channel. Your task is to take in a string of text that describes this font and return the correspond text encoded.

## Millitext Alphabet

```
CHARACTER: 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ENCODING:  WYWBMRRMMMWYWYWWWMWBMRMYGYGYCWMMMMMW
           MGBWMRRMMMMMRMRRRMGBMRWMMMMMRGMMMMMB
           MGWWWWWBWWWYRMWWMWGBYRWMMYMYGGMMWGGG
           MGRBBBMBMBMMRMRRMMGBMRMMMRWMBGMCWMGR
           WWWWBWWBWWMYWYWRWMWWMWMMGRCMYGWBMMGW
```

I've abbreviated each color to a one character symbol (R=red, G=green, B=blue, C=cyan, Y=yellow, M=magenta, W=white).

## Input Format

The input format for this is pretty open. You can have the input be an array containing each column, an array containing each row, a `char[][]`, or anything like that. You can also choose to use the full words "red", "green", "blue", with uppercase/lowercase of your choice (but it must be consistent for each word! You cannot use "RED" and also do "green" or "Blue").

If your language happens to support it, you can also have input be colors (however that might work, I don't know off-hand).

You can assume that the input will ONLY contain encoded characters in the alphabet above (in particular, there will be no spaces or punctuation in your output).

## Output Format

You can either output a string or some sort of character array. You can chose whether the letters are uppercase or lowercase, but they must all have the same case.

## Example

```
MWRRGMGYRY
MRRRMMMMRM
WWRRMWMYRM -> HELLOWORLD
MRRRMWMMRM
MWWWGMGMMY
```

## Rules

This is code golf, so shortest answer wins!

## Test set

```
WYWBMRRMMMWYWYWWWMWBMRMYGYGYCWMMMMMW
MGBWMRRMMMMMRMRRRMGBMRWMMMMMRGMMMMMB
MGWWWWWBWWWYRMWWMWGBYRWMMYMYGGMMWGGG -> THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG
MGRBBBMBMBMMRMRRMMGBMRMMMRWMBGMCWMGR
WWWWBWWBWWMYWYWRWMWWMWMMGRCMYGWBMMGW
```

Answer (score 0):

[moved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194087/make-korean-character-multi-style-ascii-box-art)

Comment: It's better to specify exactly what constitutes a valid output, rather than just saying "you can make up your own." That way we know what golfing tricks are permitted and what aren't.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Okay. Since it is code-golf, not popularity contest, that would be better. I'll fix that.

Comment: Bonuses/penalties in [tag:code-golf] is [not](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8512/83048) [okay](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/83048)

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Can this be more self-contained? It seems that the majority of the question is hidden behind links to other sites.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wanted to, but if I contain Korean character ascii arts in article, it gets so long. So I separated it. I though too long question is not good. If long question is okay, then I'll change it.

Comment: @LegenDUST You could put all input-output in the same code-block, then a scrollbar is added automatically and the challenge is still self-contained. Then again, in the link you provided I only see ASCII arts for single or combinations of 2 Korean characters, whereas the examples have 3 Korean characters combined, so if all triplet-Korean characters are added as ASCII art it's quite a big list to scroll through..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for tip!

Comment: Seconding the recommendation against bonuses, I would make proper indentation required.

Comment: @lirtosiast I'll think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## I Love U So Much!

Just print `i love u`, or `I Love U`.

But, because `i` love `u` so much, there is two rule.

1. At least there must be one `I`, and one `U`. Capital or not is regardless.
2. **Every** `I` and `U` must be stick together. No sole `i` and sole `u`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code with byte wins.

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: What is preventing me from just putting a comment or no-op at the end with `#IU` or something similar?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Ah, I forgot that. **Every** I and U must be stick together.

Comment: That's better, but it still allows, for example, BrainFuck to just type out the necessary `>` and `<` and put `IU` at the end as a comment/no-op. If that is your intention, that's fine, just wanting to point it out.

Comment: IMO this is too boring to be worth posting. The string isn't compressible, so it's just a case of taking the string `"ui love "`, rotating by one character, and printing (finding a workaround in the languages where one would normally print with `print`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe I could make string more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

## Trace My Triangles

*Triangular* is a 2D programming language that reads its code in the shape of the smallest triangle that the code will fit into, ignoring all whitespace. Its IP starts at the very top point of the triangle, and traverses the code starting in a Southeast direction. The IP's direction can be changed with the following directional switches (Note that "." is a no-op):

```
   ^
  ` /
 < . >  
  , \
   v
```

---

### Challenge

You will be given a single input string `p` which represents a valid Triangular program. Your task is to write a program or function, which will print or return the actual execution order of `p`. Instructions in `p` which are never reached by the IP can be ignored.
You may assume the following:

- `p` will contain only characters which are necessary for a Triangular program to be valid; no need to account for whitespace.
- `p` will only switch directions via the directional switches listed above. The `o`,`e`,`c` and `z` instructions will not be used.

### Examples

```
Input:                    Output:
---------------------------------------------------
F\(?)1/%-<                F(1<-%/?\)

,%./                      ,%/

\@~/;<                    \~<;/@

123456                    136
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest byte count wins.

---

## Sandbox

- Is this a good idea for a question/not a dupe?
- Is the requirement clear enough?
- What other test cases should I be adding, if any?
- Should jump-related instructions - `(`, `)` and `]` - also be among the things that can be disregarded?
- Should any other sorts of instructions be disregarded?
- Would any other assumptions make this more manageable/fun?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find a challenge which will return as an integer how many days until Christmas based on an input like DDDD-MM-YY. So...

## How many days until Christmas?

Work out the number of full days until Christmas based on today's date based on the Western Christianity date [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas).

Write a program, method, function, routine or sub-routine that accepts an input of the current date according the the Gregorian calendar [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). The date may be in any format as long as you use the full year (so `2019-09-11` rather than `19-09-11`). Other than requiring the full year, the date format is up to you (DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY or even formally written dates like Wednesday 12th June 2019). Please state what date format you are using in your answer.

An integer is displayed according to your standard output.

Example:

```
input -> output:

12/06/2019 -> 196 days until Christmas*
12/25/2019 -> 0 days until Christmas**

* DD/MM/YYYY format
** MM/DD/YYYY format
```

Comment: Subset of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15660/43319)?

Comment: @Adám Or really similar to [Christmas Eve Eve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/178003/42963), just accumulate the days rather than printing "Eve."

Comment: Yes, thanks. Those challenges are specifically for technologies that have DateTime functions built in, my suggested challenge would be more suitable for technologies that don't know what date it is or what timezone they are in, like the Sinclair and Commodore 8-bit machines, for instance. Because you would have to specify the date and the rest would have to be worked out with some programmings.

Answer (score 0):

## Output Ordinal Numbers up to n

**Moved to [Output Ordinal Numbers up to n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188363/output-ordinal-numbers-up-to-n).**

Answer (score 0):

## Continue a progression [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

The \$k\$th generalized mean \$M_k\$ of a set of numbers is defined as $$M_k(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\root^k\of{\frac{a_1^k+\dots+a_n^k}n}.$$
\$M_0\$, the geometric mean, is defined through a limit \$\lim_{k\to0} \root^k\of{\frac{a_1^k+\dots+a_n^k}{n}} = \root^n\of{a_1\cdot\dots\cdot a_n}\$. \$k\$ does not have to be integer.

An arithmetic progression is (according to Wikipedia) a sequence of numbers such that the difference between consecutive terms is constant. A geometric progression is a sequence of numbers such that the ratio between consecutive terms is constant.

There is a simple way to generalize these (that also explains why on earth is geometric progression named geometric): for a progression of order \$k\$ for any 3 consecutive elements \$a\$,\$b\$,\$c\$ \$M_k(a,c)=b\$. This way, the arithmetic progression is of order 1 and the geometric progression is of order 0. The order does not have to be integer.

The task is, given 3 real positive numbers \$a,b,c\$, to find the next term in the progression formed by them.

### Notes

- If multiple valid outputs exist, you can output any of them.
- It is guaranteed that a valid output exists.
- An output is valid if \$|o_{correct}-o_{program}| \le10^{-5} \cdot \max(o_{correct}, 1)\$.

## Sandbox stuff

- I still have to prepare some test cases, especially for non-integer orders.
- Has this been asked before?
- Do multiple correct outputs ever exist? I feel like very often there are infinitely many.
- Does Mathematica have a built-in?
- Should I add a time limit? I feel like brute-forcing all floating point numbers and checking if they are valid outputs might be shorter than actually calculating.
- Should I restrict the order to be integer, or even just 0 or 1 (leaving only arithmetic and geometric progressions)?
- Is there a simple and beautiful formula for the next term that I was unable to find and that all answers will have to copy from each other? I could neither get Mathematica nor myself to solve any related equations.
- Is the grammar correct enough?

Comment: I think `The task is, given 3 real positive numbers ...` is a bit problematic, as receiving them sounds like a daunting task.

Comment: @Jonathan Surely reading three numbers or taking them as function arguments or whatever is your language's alternative is the least thing you have to do here?

Comment: I think proving that submissions will always meet your validity criterion will be rather daunting. This will probably further encourage solutions that just try every single floating point number? I'd recommend saying that floating point issues won't be counted against the submission, but you still have a bit of a problem. If you do add a time limit I'd recommend saying that it only need be tested on the cases you provide (and maybe remind users that hardcoding is a loophole ;) )

Comment: The time limit only on the test cases thing makes sense to me. What does "not counting floating point issues mean"? I think most solutions will have to use binary or ternary search, and that needs a, uh, stopping precision or a iteration count to be close enough. I think we can remove the need to verify it on all numbers by preparing a lot of test cases!

Comment: Not every solution will use that, and even if they do they may still run into a problem where they can't get a solution well enough based on their native floating point type and have to do a bunch of extra work. I think it works well as a catch-all that prevents golfers from having to struggle with weird edge cases. But generally I think you are right that just having enough test cases will be good enough (also I didn't get notified by your comment because someone else has commented already, you'd need to use @).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman double-precision floating points have around 14 digits of precision, and 1e-8 is a perfectly common epsilon for such tasks (and I use 1e-5). And if I assume floating point numbers are arbitrary precision, that implicitly disallows binary/ternary search, as it will never produce the exact answer. And since the only two solutions I know are Mathematica NSolve and alternatives and searching for the order and then for the next number, this disallows all remotely interesting solutions known to me.

Comment: Assuming the languages that people use to answer your challenge will use a reasonable convention is not a particularly good one! I didn't meant arbitrary precision but arbitrarily larger precision based on what you have specified. It is probably fine the way you have it, I just think it is better to think about nonstandard languages when you can. If you put no time limit, some solutions may try to iterate over all floating point numbers of a particular precision, for example. Sorry if this has gotten out of hand, maybe I'm not doing a good job explaining what I mean?

Comment: So in short, given inputs \$a,b,c\$ find a \$k\$ such that \$a^k + c^k = 2b^k\$ and then find and output a \$d\$ such that \$d^k = 2c^k - b^k\$? There is a significant problem in that \$k=0\$ is always a solution to the first equation, so I think that the geometric mean would have to be tested first as a special case.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think so. I feel like there actually _is_ a simple and beautiful solution that everyone will have to copy from each other here.

Answer (score 0):

## Nearest match with limited values

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

When writing my solution for [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186740/print-the-phrase-and-she-said-but-thats-his-using-only-the-alphabet), I found that I needed to generate a target value using nothing but multiplication and increments/decrements, using a restricted set of values to use in the multiplication. Given that my choice of values was restricted, I had to brute-force what the optimum solution was. gObviously, this seems like a programming challenge!

The challenge is this: Given a target value *t* and set of allowed multiplier/multiplicand values, find the solution *t*=*x*×*y*±*c* (*x* and *y* are from the set of allowed values), that has the smallest value of *c*. If *c* is zero, indicate the solution as an exact match.

As this is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, smallest code size wins. The [standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Example program (ungolfed): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRtb5swEP7Or/BaVYLkWG0nwaYJndIsSPva7cPUDFWMkIaIQhVIF3Xqb@8OAyZr2klDurN9PL6X52xH9l0UvZwmWZTuljGZFOUyyT@uL42/TVmJtpfHPFmS5H6X3kZhGpk7NDPntiRluL2LSyCVQeK69ximu7gAUiRPMa6z3X1tschvgxBEkXy1KuKyWOhfPT0LFoMAELSM9x4FEqV5ERelZ7OxgZtX@dasHCQeHZNkonfhot@3ENBBNhVkcwjZ9PuNZ8SqXKqvy8erK7HNesMiCZpSFpvAGh/A78O7LCmRHs@sd15S61M9u7DrUWVbfW2pKm6woIGnvY/fhjAN2bwH4YH3KkyyMhuqJtRqbESzpxNu/cVpEVd79I9JA/3n3i7WB23tiCTkYYvsrMyT@T6MSlLk6a5M8uyCnH1f91A8lB/ZCRDNgJ5ucFqzr4kmZBuXu23Wrp@NWuPwa52ksWnbio02gYM@HrE1Nv6rdU2RHdZr2dHFtqWaTW1WVeRZf6lrPOo7HPf5DVTvXdARQYf0VOQ8G88vp8t4lWQxmV5ff/1yMzeRHbO6hvkKp@ftDONYlmHUfCSZWd3surRoHW7bngReXawLbAAc7@J5j3wLfwKZXePdfgijmPTOFcIZgeOAI8CR4LggKAgGgoMYgBiCGIFwQAgQEoQLkoJkIDnIAcghyBFIB6QAKUG64NZxpvZN69wV4EpwMQtKURgKRxmgDFFGKA6KQJEoiGOIY4hjiMPUGUMcQxxDHEMcQxxDHNbEOOI4VzFD@6mNSffzKVT6SumZ0p@VnivtQ4PzabX2mdJc6YHSQ6VHSjtKC6Wl0q7SKoavYvgqhq9i@CqG71c9VZfu1VPbtYbu@ZArv3wuVFwuhIo85I2d8lk9zpRvzupxNKVD7f/Vq9oeniaadfC4ds9/m0p3iUGfuua5Vye1PqWEjvF0/gE)

---

I don't think that I saw this particular challenge before, but I may have missed some. This is my first challenge, so please let me know how I can make it better!

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox! This is mostly fine, except for two main things: "indicate that the solution as an exact match" is not really fleshed out enough, and that you don't have any test cases in the body. There are some other minor things, like specifying `t` and the allowable values to be integers (can they be negative?), and if returning all of the optimal `x,y` pairs is acceptable. As a challenge, I'm a bit unsure if this is particularly interesting due to its simplicity, but I don't think it is so simple that it is bad or anything.

Answer (score 0):

### GPA calculator

A GPA is sort of weighted average based on the grades obtained in certain courses.  There are a number of different systems, but for this challenge we'll use the following grades and their numeric values:

```
A: 4
B: 3
C: 2
D: 1
F: 0
P: —
```

The grade is P is a special case.  For some courses, students can sign up to take a course as Pass/Fail.  In the case of a Pass (P), the course has *no effect* on their GPA whatsoever, but in the case of a Fail (F), the course *does* affect the GPA.

All courses are weighted by the number of hours/credits they are taken for.  So give the following transcript:

```
Course            Hours   Grade
------            -----   -----
Next Gen Perl       6       A
Advanced C-minar    1       C
Starting with Java  3       B
```

We would calculate the total points as 35 (`6*4 + 1*2 + 3*3`), and then divide it by the number of hours, or 10 (`6+1+3`) for a final GPA of **3.5**.  If Starting with Java had been given an F, the total points would be 26 with 10 hours, for a GPA of **2.6**.  However, if it had been a P, the total points would still be 26, but with only 7 hours, the GPA would be **3.71428571429…**

### Input

An arbitrarily long list/array/sequence/etc of transcript entries.  The entries are simply a two item list/array/sequence/etc with one item being an integer value (doesn't have to be an actual Int value, floats are fine) of hours, and the other being the string ('A','B'...).  The above example would have been:

```
[
  [6, 'A'],
  [1, 'C'],
  [3, 'B']
]
```

You may assume that the list will have at least one computable grade (so no empty transcripts, nor transcripts consisting only of P).  If your language does not have strings, then you may use numbers for A/B/C/D/F/P, but their values must be similarly spaced (e.g. 10,11,12,13,14,**25**)

### Output

A number representing the GPA (float or other non-Int value)

### Scoring and Restrictions

Codegolf, so shortest code in bytes wins.  Standard rules apply.

### Sandbox questions

I thought about allowing for either +/- grades (A+, A, A-, B+...) which would definitely prevent using ASCII values as easily, but then that led me to the thought of having a second input which is a list of possible grades with their equivalent value, but I think that would start over complicating it and way over benefit languages with built-in hashing.  Thoughts?

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150370/31625)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman not a dupe.  This one adds the P which makes it a good bit more complciated.

Comment: I disagree, solutions can just filter out all the grades with `P` and then exactly reuse the result from the question I linked. Unless I've missed something that definitely fits in the criteria for being a duplicate.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Between filtering, vastly different input/output (all of which could/would significantly modify entries — the input/output in particular was a strong criticism of the one you linked to), I think it's sufficiently different and golfed answers wouldn't be trivially different.   But in any case, I asked about feeding in +/- or arbitrary grades which absolutely would be a totally different question.  Perhaps instead of being dismissive, you could be constructive.

Comment: It is possible that I'm being too harsh, but I don't think I am. The only real problem with the other question compared to this one is the rounding, which could basically just be dropped from the answers. While I agree that this isn't identical, I don't think it has enough reason to exist as even with the +/- grades it's still just looking up values then applying a weighted average. It is certainly possible that I am in the minority, but I think my skepticism should encourage you to find other people's opinions before posting.

Comment: I agree with @FryAmTheEggman; the core of both challenges is identical. The only real difference here is having to filter the `P`s which is a trivial modification for most languages. Having said that, though, I wouldn't swing my hammer at this until a few solutions had been posted, in the hope that I would be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Meta command-line flag parsing [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### The challenge

Write a program or function which determines whether or not a chosen command-line flag has been passed into the compiler or interpreter, but without accessing command-line parameters directly.

#### Details

- You must take in no input.
- You are free to choose the flag that is being detected, but it must:

  - be a flag, meaning a boolean command-line parameter that does not take any arguments (e.g. `-O3` in gcc)
  - not print anything by virtue of being present (e.g. flags that print a version number or usage help are disallowed)
- The output must be 1 if the flag is present, and 0 otherwise.
- The program must successfully run without errors, whether or not the flag is present.
- You may not make use of the arguments passed to the compiler/interpreter, whether directly by value or by a property such as string length, array length.
- Separately from the chosen flag, other command line parameters can be used, so long as they remain the same when running the code with and without the flag in question.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest answer in bytes wins!

---

### Sandbox Questions

- Are there any other edge cases or loopholes that should be accounted for here?
- Is this a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), despite the challenge not being related to input?

Feedback welcome!

Comment: I think this may have quite a few problems with determining what counts as a valid flag, what counts as accessing them, and what counts as an error. For example, Pyth has a flag `-d` which turns on debug printing. So any program with constant output would work. But that doesn't seem like what you have in mind, would it be acceptable?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Indeed, that's somewhat problematic. Maybe restricting output to either 1 or 0 would stop such trivial solutions from passing, though at the cost of punishing some other languages. I don't want to completely bar short-but-clever solutions, though, as I find that they can often be surprisingly creative; the example you posted is just something that would end up being used in too many solutions.

Comment: That may help, but you are right that it will restrict solutions a lot. I think this is a challenge that is worth running past quite a few people so you can get an idea of which flags are actually worth (and possible) to rule out.

Comment: Thinking of Japt here which takes its flags via an HTML `input`: if I'm understanding correctly, I wouldn't be allowed to simply read the `value` of that `input`, right? What about accessing Japt's internal variable for storing flags, would that be allowed? Also, should our solutions run no matter which flag is used or need we only support our chosen flag and no flag? Again thinking of Japt which has a flag that negates it's output; obviously that's going to be problematic!

Comment: @Shaggy Both the input and internal variable would classify as "accessing the list of arguments", which is disallowed. Only two sets of command line parameters need to be supported: `[some set of starting parameters not including the chosen flag, if any]` and `[the same set of starting parameters] + [the chosen flag]`. I'll try to clarify both of these things.

Answer (score 0):

### Conversion

Assume that there is a number `a`. In every conversion of that number, the number can either convert itself to its value plus the value of one of its digits, or convert itself to its value minus the value of one of its digits.

In this situation, find the minimum number of conversions one has to make in order to get to the number `b`. If b cannot be reached, output `-1`.

### Input

Input one line containing the integers a and b (where 1 <= a, and b <= 10^6).

### Output

Output a line containing one integer, which represents the minimum amount that one has to convert the number.

### Example input and output (s)

```
Input:  1 10
Output: 5
```

Why?

```
   1
-> 1+1=2
-> 2+2=4
-> 4+4=8
-> 8+8=16
-> 16-6=10
=> 10
```

Comment: At first sight this looks like just another shortest path question, but reachability is actually quite subtle. Do you have a proof of decidability?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer chain: decreasing character scores

Assign a non-negative integer value to each letter in the alphabet, and write a function or program which takes as input a character string and outputs the sum of of the values of the letters in the string. Characters outside of [a-z] and [A-Z] have value 0.

Now run your code, taking as input the code of each of the previous answers in the order they were posted (including your own). The resulting sequence of scores should be *strictly decreasing*.

For example, if you are 4th to answer and your code defines a function \$f\$, then the output should verify
\$f(c_1)>f(c_2)>f(c_3)>f(c_4)\$ where \$c_1\$ is the code of the 1st answer, \$c_2\$ is the code of the 2nd answer, ..., \$c_4\$ is the code of your answer.

When there will have been one week with no new answer, the 2nd-to-last answer will be declared the winner.

#### Clarifications:

- The values you assign may be the same as or different from those used by previous answers.
- The value 0 is allowed.
- Different letters may be assigned the same value.
- Upper and lower case versions of the same letter may have different values.
- Letters with diacritics, such as `é` or `Ä`, have value 0.
- Your code need not handle letters which have not occurred in any of the previous answers (so if no answer so far has used the letter `W`, it's OK if your code fails on strings with a `W`).

Comment: Using characters like this seems to have some problems. Do answers get to pick encodings? Or is it really more like \$ f(c_{1},e_{1}) \$ where \$ e_{i} \$ is the encoding used by the ith answer? I think this may work better if you say it should work on bytes, then answerers can choose to interpret those bytes as characters in whatever encoding they want.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I have been thinking about this as well. I want it to be easy to set up on TIO, which means that solvers should be able to just copy-paste the code of previous answers. Forcing solvers to take into account the esoteric codepoints of golfing languages would be a hassle. I'd be more inclined to let answerers pick the encoding, but I suppose that might create potential loopholes.

Comment: Wouldn't asking for a hexdump of the code to be in each answer ensure that the solutions are fairly accessible? TIO also has problems with displaying particular characters (null bytes especially) and other things like that each text box has one fixed encoding.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How about restricting to letters (without diacritics)? Anything not in [a-z] or [A-Z] must have value 0. I think this circumvents the problem. Or maybe extend to letters+digits, or even all ASCII characters.

Comment: I don't think that works with your setup at all because a submission with no characters in whatever range you pick must always score exactly zero so it necessarily ends the chain.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes, and then whoever submitted that is guaranteed to lose, since the second-to-last answer wins.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry. It still seems to have trouble with languages that could write all of their code using bytes outside the range you select and then throw in a small number of other characters, but I don't know if that is "broken" enough to make it unfun.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Potentially, an answerer could use only non-letters, add a single `a`, and then all following answers would need to assign a large value to `a` and avoid that letter in their own code. That seems OK to me, but I am a fan of lipograms... 
Anyway, I have updated the challenge following this helpful discussion; let's see if there are further comments. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Can a letter be assigned the value 0? That would be a non-negative integer

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, 0 is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Enable 2-char Jsfuck

Provide a shortest code that makes JavaScript able to do everything JavaScript is supposed to do, i.e. able to access(so no deleting `[].prototype.toString` unless you have a backup, even if you can simulate one `[].prototype.toString`) and `exec` anything, with only `[` and `]`. You can choose your environment(FF/node/etc). Answering in 6-char JsFuck or something similar is welcomed.

E.g. If you run

```
Array.prototype[''] = 'a';
Array.prototype['a'] = 'b';
Array.prototype['b'] = function() { console.log(this[0]); };
```

then `[][[]]` = `[]['']` = `'a'`, and `[][[][[]]]` = `[]['a']` = `'b'`, so `[[][[]]][[][[][[]]]]` = `['a']['b']` = `function(){console.log('a')}`.

Of course, this is an invalid answer, because it can't do `prompt`(web browser) or `fs`(node) or anything similar, or even calling the `console.log`.

Comment: This is not clear as is. Are we making a transpiler from JS to JSFuck with the winning criterion [tag:code-golf]? Do we need to support all JS input, or just some subset?

Comment: So a solution like translating `"[[]"→(  "[]["→)  "[]]"→+  "][["→[  "][]"→]  "]]["→!` is valid?

Comment: @lirtosiast I said "makes JS able to do everything in2c", not "make a language that do everything"

Comment: @Adám I don't think it's possible. `+[]` turns into `[]]][[][]` which is not even valid JS code

Comment: @l4m2 Please include your not-golfed reference implementation so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: @l4m2 If I understand this right, you're saying that we should write code that modifies the JavaScript environment such that all JavaScript code can be converted into JavaScript code that only uses characters `[` and `]`. Basically, add something to `Array.prototype` that makes the `[]` characters JavaScript-complete.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 right

Answer (score 0):

## Find the closest hex colour shorthand

In CSS, colours can be specified by a "hex triplet" - a three byte (six digit) hexadecimal number where each byte represents the red, green, or blue components of the colour. For instance, `#FF0000` is completely red, and is equivalent to `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

Colours can also be represented by the shorthand notation which uses three hexadecimal digits. The shorthand expands to the six digit form by duplicating each digit. For instance, `#ABC` becomes `#AABBCC`.

Since there are fewer digits in the hex shorthand, fewer colours can be represented.

### The challenge

Write a program or function that takes a six digit hexadecimal color code and outputs the closest three-digit color code, where closeness is measured by adding together the difference between each component of the full color code and the corresponding component of the shorthand color code.

Here's an example:

> - Input hex code: #28a086
> - red component
>
>   - 0x28 = 40 (decimal)
>   - 0x22 = 30
>   - 0x33 = 51
>   - 0x22 is closer, so the first digit of the shortened color code is 2
> - green component
>
>   - 0xa0 = 160
>   - 0x99 = 153
>   - 0xaa = 170
>   - 0x99 is closer, so the second digit is 9
> - blue component
>
>   - 0x86 = 134
>   - 0x77 = 119
>   - 0x88 = 136
>   - 0x88 is closer, so the third digit is 8
> - The shortened color code is #298

Your program or function must accept as input a six digit hexadecimal color code prepended with `#` and output a three digit color code prepended with `#`.

### Examples

- #FF0000 → #F00
- #00FF00 → #0F0
- #D913C4 → #D1C
- #C0DD39 → #BD3
- #28A086 → #298
- #C0CF6F → #BC7

Comment: [Closely related, not a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59794/42963).

Comment: There's probably a better way to phrase the challenge

Comment: @AdmBorkBork [Related - kinda like the inverse of this challenge, although not exactly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/better-hex-color-codes-for-your-internet/)

Comment: Maybe you could add an example of how the closeness is determined (for example for the `C0` -> `B` of the last test case).

Answer (score 0):

Tag: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Arrays

I originally wrote it in Chinese and am still working on translating it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Given an array containing n integers A1,A2,…,An, where all of their initial values are 0. Please implement the four operations to the array described below:

### Operations

````
Given the positive integer x and y, let every number in the range Ax~Ay (including Ax and Ay) be added by the given positive integer c;
Given the positive integer x and y, let every number in the range Ax~Ay be (similarly to the previous spec; the rest of the spec also conforms that rule) multiplied by a given positive integer c;
Given the positive integer x and y, let every number in the range Ax~Ay be changed to a given positive integer c;
Given the positive integer x and y, with regard to a given positive integer p, evaluate the value of the following expression :```[pow(Ax, p) + pow(A(x + 1), p) + … + pow(Ay, p)]7```
````

### Input

In the first line of the test case, there are two positive integers n(where 1<=n), which represents the length of the array.

Then, input operations sequentially, where each operation occupies one line, and the input will be 4 positive integers as in: `type x y num`, where type is either 1, 2, 3, or 4; these identifiers correspond to the corresponding operation as described above. The meaning of x and y corresponf to the description (where 1<=x<=y<=n). When type is not 4, num will be the positive integer given c(where 1<=c<=10000); when type is 4, num will be the given positive integer p(where 1<=p<=3)。

### Output

For each test case, for every 4 operation for the array, output the value of the corresponding expression.

### Example input

```
5
3 3 5 7
1 2 4 4
4 1 5 2
2 2 5 8
4 3 5 3
```

### Example output

```
307
7489
```

Comment: Is it supposed to have restricted-complexity? Or pure golf?

Comment: I will add the category later after I translate the problem.

Comment: In that case it's [tag:restricted-time]. But you have to specify exactly how it is tested. 8 seconds doesn't mean much without the test cases and the the exact computer it will run on. [tag:restricted-complexity] is much simpler. And just to confirm, you wrote this question, and it's not a homework problem from elsewhere, is it?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the question; I will accept your suggestion.

Comment: Because, I think it is designed to be O(n+qlogn) in some algorithm competition. If more than that, any straightforward algorithm will probably work, and it's better to just removed the restriction. (Also note that on CG.se, in a challenge that there is a known best algorithm, coming up with the algorithm is generally not supposed to be the main challenge. If you go for O(n+qlogn), they will simply ask for a reference algorithm.)

Comment: Don't use multiple test cases. Make the list format flexible and q implicit. I'm not sure what's the best way to input multiple operations, but at least you could make operation types consistent and distinct value. If there is no time or complexity limit you don't need mod 10007. Even if there is a limit, it is probably better to make this an input.

Comment: I think if you wrote this you probably know that O(n+qlogn) and O(n^3) (or simply without restriction) makes a lot of differences. The code would be much longer for O(n+qlogn). And for reference, [this question asking for suffix tree or alternatives](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47249/25180) had the first and only non-deleted answer about 2 years later. Not that you can't post it in either case, but... just make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: I mean at least you could make operation types *any* consistent and distinct values, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 0):

### Tips for golfing in H

As for [H as described here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17827#17827), what general tips do you have for golfing in H? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems. Tips have to be specific to H (e.g. "remove comments" is an answer).

Tips in [Standard H](http://dcoj.wmh3.com/cscos/h/) are also on-topic, although its spec is in a bad condition. You can use the H description provided in the first link to solve anything you don't understand about.

Please post one tip per answer. Also, please specify which H implementation you are using if your code runs only under a specific H implementation, as different H implementations can have different behavior.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)

Comment: Why do you want to ask this when H doesn't even exist?

Comment: What's the rush? Also, H as linked, isn't a programming language, and it has a very strict definition, so there's no much room for golfing. The only thing I can think of is to omit quotes in the rare instances where you want a string that looks like one of the 1999 integers in the range -999–999.

Comment: That would be [a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages).

Comment: [Tips for golfing in Turing Machine but Way Worse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182088/tips-for-golfing-in-turing-machine-but-way-worse) also only has 1 tip.

Comment: I can also think of a lot of those examples, as in: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19423/tips-for-golfing-in-io https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101557/tips-for-golfing-in-wierd https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96682/tips-for-golfing-in-starry

Comment: It does not matter whether it is a programming language or not; this question only cares whether H can be golfed or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Golf an H quine [duplicate]

Your task is to write a quine program in H (described in my esolangs.org [userpage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:A/H_spec)). (It is unclear whether it is possible.) Referring to [Computer Science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111358/can-standard-h-create-a-quine), which seems unappropriate.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Comment: Can you explain your comment? I cannot understand it.

Comment: Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.* Is there any reason someone wanting to golf a quine in H would not just answer [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/43319)?

Comment: Now your espolangs userpage says *Programming Puzzles and Code Golf*. This is just what *PPCG* stands for. We are not called that any more.

Comment: I am trying to retain the style of the rest of the esolangs pages. (e.g. see [this page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Esolang:Community_portal))

Comment: Information contained in public Wikis does occasionally get stale. You should update all those references to PPCG.

Comment: To clarify: is the current name "Code golf & Coding challenges"?

Comment: [The tour page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) seems to say **Code Golf Stack Exchange**.

Comment: @Adám Wait, we're now known as CCSE? :S I thought the new name was indeed "Code Golf & Coding Challenges" (CGCC)..

Comment: As for the 'challenge', we already have [a general quine challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good) as linked by @Adám in his first comment. When you have more rep you could offer a bounty on that challenge stating you want to see if someone could come up with a quine in H. But, is H even released yet? If yes, maybe the first step might be to ask _Dennis_ in [the Nineteenth Byte Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) to add H to [TIO](https://tio.run/#), and also have a github with the source code/compiler of H.

Comment: The new site name is "Code Golf", and the subtitle is "& coding challenges". You can refer to the site with or without the subtitle

Comment: (referring to it off site should probably include "Stack Exchange" as other golfing sites are available)

Comment: [Relevant](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17846/43319)

Answer (score 0):

## Machine Learning Golf: Fashion MNIST

The [first instance of Machine Learning Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187562/machine-learning-golf-multiplication) received a lot of intention but also revealed some problems (mostly caused by people in this community being too clever ;-)).

I intend to address those issues in this second installment:

Fashion MNIST is a dataset of 60,000 labelled 28x28 pixel grayscale images of fashion items (T-shirts/tops, Trousers, Pullovers, Dresses, Coats, Sandals, Shirts, Sneakers, Bags and Ankle boots).

Your task is to design and train a neural network that correctly identifies these images. Here are the rules:

**Performance Goal**

To qualify, your model must achieve at least 95% accuracy on the training set (i.e. you must identify at least 57,000 images correctly).

**Rules**

You may use any language and framework of your choice.

Your dataset must be taken as the current version of Fashion MNIST found [here](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist) or in the references listed in that repo's README (for convenience).

You may reshape, permutate, rescale and offset entries in the dataset. However, modifications made to one entry must be performed on all entries.

You may transform the labels any way you like. (But you may, obviously, not change which labels correspond to which images.)

During training, you're allowed to use any dataset you want (in fact, you are allowed to come up with your weights however you like). Hence the above limitations are only relevant to assess whether your model meets the stated performance goal.

Your model

- must be a 'traditional' feed forward neural network, i.e.a node's value is calculated as a weighted linear combination of some of the nodes in previous layers (which may include a bias node with constant value 1) followed by an activation function. Note that this allows you to skip layers and use convolutional/residual layers,
- may only use the following standard activation functions:

  1. \$\mathrm{linear}(x) = x\$,
  2. \$\mathrm{softmax}(\vec{x})_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_j e^{x_j}}\$,
  3. \$\mathrm{selu}_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = \begin{cases}
     \beta \cdot x & \text{, if } x > 0 \\
     \alpha \cdot \beta (e^x -1 ) & \text{, otherwise}
     \end{cases}\$,
  4. \$\mathrm{softplus}(x) = \ln(e^x+1)\$,
  5. \$\mathrm{leaky-relu}_\alpha(x) = \begin{cases}
     x & \text{, if } x < 0 \\
     \alpha \cdot x & \text{, otherwise}
     \end{cases}\$,
  6. \$\tanh(x)\$,
  7. \$\mathrm{sigmoid}(x) = \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}\$,
  8. \$\mathrm{hard-sigmoid}(x) = \begin{cases}
     0 & \text{, if } x < -2.5 \\
     1 & \text{, if } x > 2.5 \\
     0.2 \cdot x + 0.5 & \text{, otherwise}
     \end{cases}\$,
  9. \$e^x\$
- must take a single entry of the (preprocessed) training set as its only input and
- return the predicted label, in the format you've specified, as its only output,
- if a given weight occurs multiple times in your model, you may reuse it to lower your overall score,

Your answer must include (or link to) all code necessary to check your results -- including the trained weights of your model. In particular, you must include all preprocessing steps of your dataset.

**Scoring**

The neural network with the *smallest number of weights* (including bias weights) wins.

Parameters used to preprocess your data don't count as weights.

Enjoy!

**Baseline**

There is a [tutorial for the Fashion MNIST dataset available on Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) which serves as an excellent starting point if you decide to use TF as your framework.

---

This challenge had already been posted on the main site and got closed there. The purpose of this post is threefold:

1. Is the community interested in this particular (and this kind of) challenge (in general)?
2. How can the user experience for the target audience be improved? Specifically:

   - What are likely causes of confusion?
   - Can we streamline the structure?
   - Are some of the rules too restrictive or not restrictive enough?
   - Are there any loopholes I've overlooked? (For instance, preprocessing the training data opens up the possibility of encoding labels into the feature set. Some of the rules are already designed to prohibit this but it's entirely possible that they don't suffice.)
3. Any other constructive feedback?

Comment: I think a lot of community members don't know anything about machine learning. You might try saving this one for later and working to think of some entry-level challenges that work as a sort of tutorial when done together.

Comment: @mbomb007 While I like the idea, it seems pretty tough to come up with challenges that are both simple enough to solve without knowing machine learning and yet won't just get solved without using ML at all. That's what happened with my [entry-level challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187562/machine-learning-golf-multiplication). Still, I'm sure there are a few people here who would enjoy this kind of challenge and seeing them might spark the interest of others.

Comment: I think it's worth considering the questions and requests for clarifications you were asked in the comments of your previous challenge and making sure you've clearly addressed all of them here.

Comment: I think there's a good chance the best strategy for this challenge isn't anything that looks like training a neural net, but some form of massive over-fitting like looking up a few specifically-chosen pixels with a lookup table, implemented with neural net primitives. I'd suggest you make a good effort at trying to optimize both strategies yourself to see how that turns out.

Comment: @xnor The previous issues have been addressed, as far as I can tell, and I'm not concerned about overfitting. If you can identify a few relevant bits of information to pass the test while staying within the rules, that's fine with me.

Comment: I should make clear that the intention of this challenge is to provoke people to come up with tricky ways to lower their score -- it's not meant to result in neural networks you would actually use in production. Hence I'd like the rules only to guard against approaches that trivialize this task (like encoding labels into the feature set via preprocessing). And testing indicates that you might be able to come up with a solution using \$\ll 1000\$ weights -- beating every traditional approach by a long shot. (Which, to me, is  pretty exciting.)

Comment: If doing hardcoding-style stuff is fine, then it's confusing to mention training as in "Your task is to design and train a neural network" if training is actually optional. And  "I intend to address those issues in this second installment" makes it sound to me like you're trying to make the challenge watertight against unexpected clever approaches, which I think isn't what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Let me also reiterate what mbomb007 said about many community members not knowing anything about machine learning. I think it would be good to write up a friendly introduction with everything that's needed for the challenge while keeping unfamiliar terminology to a minimum. Separately, scoring by distinct weights strikes me as a really bad idea. I wouldn't be surprised if the optimal score is 1, achieved by an enormous network all with only weight 1 that encodes the whole dataset using its topology or its choice of gates. Even convolution layers seem very exploitable combined with copying.

Comment: @xnor 'if training is actually optional'.. Hardcoding weights, as far as I'm concerned, is a form of training. That's fine -- you may come up with your weights any way you like. But I think you're right about the distinct weights bit. I'll add a mathematically precise definition of what I have in mind that will also serve as a rough introduction to neural networks. I didn't intially want to do that because I think it distracts from the actual challenge but at this point I'm convinced it needs to be done to avoid disputes.

Comment: @xnor, yes: it's quite easy to show that \$\textrm{selu}_{0,1}\$ and weight -1 gives a Turing-complete system.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That can't be right. You have to, at least, allow recurrent layers or some similar feature. Otherwise you won't be able to model the Ackermann function.

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate a constant from its characteristic function

You are given in some language-dependent way (e.g. a lambda parameter) a characteristic function which is basically another way of saying a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) function. This function will take an integer input and return `true` or `false`, or `1` or `0`, or any other two 1-byte values of your choice. You can decide whether you need the function to be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

Your job is then to take this function and calculate the floating-point value obtained by interpreting the values of this function as a binary fraction. You must use as many significant digits as possible. I will assume IEEE double precision by default but you many use single precision if your language specifically supports it.

For example, if a function returns the sequence `0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0` (this is OEIS A010051), then your program or function will output `0.41468250985111166` as any further terms will be less than the precision of a double-precision value.

You can decide whether you want to round the 54th significant bit up or not.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I'm missing an explicit statement of where the binary point goes. Also, some tests which cover corner cases (minimum, maximum, denormal).

Comment: @PeterTaylor The binary point goes before the first value as retrieved, so `0, 1, 1, 0, 1...` becomes `.01101...`. For corner cases would it help if I said that at least one of the first 1000 elements will be "true"?

Comment: That would eliminate 0 as a possible output, whereas I think is itself one of the corner cases. It would also eliminate denormal numbers. The smallest positive double value is [\$2^{-1074}\$](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118343).

Answer (score 0):

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

### Make a bigger number

Each answer on this question must be a complete program (not a function) that outputs a positive integer in decimal (trailing newlines are permitted).  Output should be either passed to STDOUT or displayed on the screen.  The output number must also be larger than all the numbers output by all the valid answers at the time of posting.  One person may not post two consecutive answers.

### Scoring

Your answer will be scored with the following formula

\$\dfrac{B'+1}{B+1}\$

Where \$B\$ is the number of bytes in your answer and \$B'\$ is the number of bytes in the longest answer before your answer posted by someone other than yourself.  Lower scores will be better.

Comment: Could you please clarify some more rules? E.g, in these sorts of challenges, using the same languages twice is prohibited. Even if *you're* fine with it, just clarify that to avoid confusion. Also, state when it will end and whether a lower/higher score is better. Further, some languages don't have an 'integer' type, while others have many - how could they get around this?

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi Prohibiting double language use is only used in specific scenarios it is in general it tends to be very bad rule to have as it only causes confusion.  I definitely do not see it as the default and I don't want to give the impression that it is.  Since programs have to be complete for this challenge (we are viewing programs as black boxes) types should not be a problem.  Maybe I need to make this clearer in the post.  And on the lower vs higher, that is definitely something important I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Answer chaining questions should have some inherent mechanism whereby it gets harder to answer over time. As it stands, this can run forever.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was under the impression that later answers would get harder because those challenges have scoring mechanisms that benefit later answers.

Comment: I'm not certain that I'm interpreting that comment correctly. The answer chaining challenges I've participated in didn't have scoring *per se*, but "the penultimate answer wins".

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was being a bit more general in my statement but that is the specific mechanism that I see a lot.

Comment: Hm... actually, Peter Taylor's point isn't entirely wrong. An issue I can see is that the scoring formula will probably end up making each answer at least exponentially longer than the previous one, and that two or more people could actually duel just by adding more bytes to their code, e.g. A: 50000 `9`s, B: 5E50 `9`s, A: 5*10^99E99 `9`s, etc. In my opinion, the previous scoring formula (\$\frac{B_{n-1}+1}{B_n+1}\$) was much better, but with the highest score being the leader.

Comment: I think I can parse that response, but I don't get the subtext at all, so I'll rephrase my point as a question in the hope of eliciting a concrete response: what prevents two people from spinning this out to infinity just by copying the previous answer and adding `+1`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor In my mind two things 1) it probably won't get them better scores 2) it wouldn't be very fun.  I am a little concerned though since these are not excellent motivators.  I am going to think about other scoring mechanisms that might further disincentivise this.  Or perhaps some restrictions on answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Write an X-SAMPA Interpreter

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

Write an X-SAMPA interpreter that, when given an X-SAMPA string, outputs an IPA string.

#### Some Background

[SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMPA) is a system for encoding sounds from various languages into a computer-readable ASCII format. [X-SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA) is a descendant that encodes the [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) instead. The IPA is a character set that represents (almost) all sounds that a human can make. A large majority of IPA is based on the usual Latin character set (`a-z`), along with some supplementary characters (`θ ʌ ŋ χ`, etc.).

#### The Challenge

- Input is a string of X-SAMPA.
- Translate the X-SAMPA string into IPA.
- Output is a string of IPA.
- Input and output can be given using [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- X-SAMPA charts can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA).
- Characters not defined in X-SAMPA should be ignored.
- You must implement the entirety of X-SAMPA.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest in bytes wins.

#### Samples

```
this is a test input --> this is a test input
THIS IS A TEST INPUT --> θɥɪʃ ɪʃ ɑ θɛʃθ ɪŋʋʊθ
H\El\L\0 W@R1d --> ʜɛɺʟ0 ʍəʁɨd
123456789 --> ɨøɜɾɫɐɤɵœ
d_"i_+a_-c_/r_/i_0t_hi_=c_>s_?\ --> d̈i̟a̠čři̥tʰi̩cʼsˤ
Code GO\lf & CodI\ng Challen\ges\ --> çode ɣʘlf ɶ çodᵻnɡ çhallenɡeɕ
clicks O\|\ǃ\=\|\|\ --> clicks ʘǀǃǂǁ
mixed~!@#$%^&*(){}[]<>,.?/:;"' --> mixed#$ˌ^ɶ*(͡æʉ[]<>,.ʔ
impl ejec b_<p_> --> impl ejec ɓpʼ
```

Comment: Way too many edge cases here: What about supporting impossible diacritics i.e. a character marked both syllabic and nonsyllabic? The charts should be included so the challenge is self-contained.

Comment: I was considering omitting `You must implement the entirety of X-SAMPA` and instead needing to implement only a subset, namely not the diacritics.

Comment: "Input is a string of X-SAMPA" makes "characters not defined in X-SAMPA should be ignored" redundant

Answer (score 0):

## Brute-force the switchboard

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188556/brute-force-the-switchboard)!

Comment: It looks good to me! I'll remove my old comments now. Also, thanks for using the sandbox! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you so much for the suggestions! I'll keep it up a bit longer in case anyone else remembers or finds a dupe.

Comment: Poor guy indeed having to do binary counting instead of using a Gray code...

Answer (score 0):

### The Acrobat Competition

**Anyone may post this to main once this question is done. I only care about people enjoying solving problems. (I do not want the reputation for this question.)**

After someone cloned [so](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187682/how-many-jimmys-can-fit) [many](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187731/jimmy-needs-your-help) [Jimmy's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187759/can-jimmy-hang-on-his-rope) [to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188140/jimmy-needs-a-new-pair-of-shoes) [disrupt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188391/a-scene-of-jimmy-diversity) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187586/will-jimmy-fall-off-his-platform) [world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188550/battle-of-the-jimmys), Jimmy started to be stressed about the existence of his dwarf forms; his circus leader started to ignore him, focus on the dwarves, and gradually gave him less salary.

He has to win an acrobat competition to gain attention from his leader again. (He does care about his salary.)

### Input/Output

The first line of input will contain the acrobatic power of Jimmy; it is represented as Jimmy's (`/o\`) separated with spaces; invalid Jimmy's should be ignored.

After this line, there are two lines of dwarf Jimmy's also represented by their shapes: (`o`); invalid dwarf Jimmy's should be ignored.

The combined power between two dwarf (`x` as the top line of dwarf Jimmys and `y` as the bottom line of dwarf Jimmys) is √x²+y² (the exact floating-point number).

If Jimmy's acrobatic power is larger than the two dwarf Jimmy's, output a truthy value. Otherwise, output a falsy value.

### Example input/outputs

This outputs a falsy value:

```
/o\ // o /o\ o o\ //o\\ /o\ /o\ /o\
o o o o
/o\ l o j oe o lo . o aso o feo o
```

This outputs a truthy value:

```
/o\/o\ /o\ /o\ /o\ /o\ /o\ /o\
o	o o 	 o
o	o o o	o o oo o o o o
```

Comment: `two dwarf Jimmy's` should be `two lines of dwarf Jimmy's`?

Comment: You should probably work through an example because I'm not sure what x and y relates to. Is `x` the number of dwarves in the top line, and `y` the number in the bottom?

Comment: @Veskah It looks that way.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert an exclamation mark between everything

This challenge is highly "distilled" from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188863/print-function-for-linked-list) question. Special thanks to Akababa!

In this task, you should insert an exclamation mark at the start of the string and after every character.

### Rules

- There will always be a non-empty-string input. The input will not contain tabs either. You can assume that the input only contain non-extended ASCII printable characters and newlines.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer should win.

### Examples

- 4 newlines result in 5 newline-delimited exclamation marks. It is very hard to put this as a Markdown text, so this is stated instead.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
129591 129012 129127 129582

0
```

Outputs

```
!1! !2! !3! !4! !5! !6!
!1!2!9!5!9!1! !1!2!9!0!1!2! !1!2!9!1!2!7! !1!2!9!5!8!2!
!
!0!
```

```
asd afjoK ak:e
kPrLd
    fOJOE;
    KFO
KFkepjgop sgpaoj   faj
```

Outputs

```
!a!s!d! !a!f!j!o!K! !a!k!:!e!
!k!P!r!L!d!
! ! ! ! !f!O!J!O!E!;!
! ! ! ! !K!F!O!
!K!F!k!e!p!j!g!o!p! !s!g!p!a!o!j! ! ! !f!a!j!
```

A base test case with only one character:

```
a
```

Outputs

```
!a!
```

(Auto-completion! Just kidding, there is no such thing.) Contains exclamation marks:

```
!!
!!
!!
!!
!!
```

Outputs:

```
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: "replace the null character with an exclamation mark" is misleading. Better wording is "insert an exclamation mark at the start of the string and after every character", though there could be something more concise. The challenge is rather simple but viable.

Comment: You seem to have issues with markdown in the examples: One of your examples have tabs, but they render as four spaces which is very confusing. You can have actual tabs render by using `&#9;` instead of literal tabs. Your empty input collapses to zero lines which you can fix by inserting a space which won't render. The output for that case does have a space, which is wrong.

Comment: For the 3rd example, which shows no visible input, it's worth specifying what the input is so it's obvious at a glance. Also, the output contains only one exclamation mark, suggesting there are zero characters in the 3rd input, which appears to conflict with "There will always be a non-empty input". Could you clarify what "non-empty" means? Depending on their programming language background, some people will not regard the empty string as "non-empty" so this could be confusing.

Comment: If the input can contain newlines, it's worth including test cases that include newlines too. Perhaps a multiline input and also one composed solely of newlines

Comment: May input contains exclamation marks?

Comment: @tsh Yes, I added a test case. Exclamation marks are printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Oh no, I forgot to add an objective winning criterion! Does anyone have suggestions about the criterion?(I will go with [tag:code-golf] temporarily.)

Comment: I would indeed suggest code-golf. As for the test case of only newlines. Why are there seven newlines in the input, but only five exclamation marks in the output? I would expect eight exclamation marks instead.

Comment: There should only be 4 in the sample input. I seem to have problems with Markdown.

Comment: @A__ Yeah, the markup can be a bit annoying at times. Using `<pre><code>4 newlines</code></pre>` makes it somewhat better, but not much. Maybe simply stating 4 newlines result in 5 newline-delimited exclamation marks is enough. Anyway, I've prepared two solutions for when it goes to main.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I can not ask this question on main, as my question asking limit was reached. You may want to post this question yourself if you wish.

Comment: Didn't even knew there was such a thing, but apparently [there indeed is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Probably because some of your challenges were confusing at first so people down-voted/close-voted before it was fixed after 20+ edits. Let's leave it in the Sandbox for now. Not sure if your question ban could be lifted somehow. Also, if I post this challenge myself I can't really post my two answers, since it's usually best to wait a few days before answering your own challenges. ;)

Comment: I am puzzled as to why you're question-banned. Although you have some downvotes and deleted questions (not as much of an issue on our well moderated site), you have multiple questions with positive score. Seems the algorithm should change.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Answering your own questions seems to be fine. There seems to be no problems arising when jimmy23013 [answered](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188108/tips-for-golfing-in-grass) their own question immediately after they asked it.

Comment: @A__ That's a tip question. :) For an actual challenge it would be weird posting your own solution before giving other users with the same programming language a chance first.

Comment: I see, first-posters often will get [beaten](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188973/shortest-way-to-get-a-typeerror/) by late-comers. There will be better answers if there is more time.

Comment: Yay, my question block is gone. I am going to post this on main.

Comment: [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190223/insert-between)

Answer (score 0):

### Give me the `jitter`s! / Add noise to data

When graphing data, it can often be helpful to display points as a scatterplot, but when duplicate data exist, you'll have multiple points graphed on top of one another. For fairness, we break ties at random with R's [`jitter` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/jitter.html).

### Inputs

- `x`, a numeric (floating point) array. There will be at least 3 distinct values in the array.
- `factor`, a numeric value
- `amount`, a numeric value **or** some sort of non-numeric value (your choice). You may select your desired non-numeric sentinel value for `amount`.

### Output

- A single array `y` where:

  - `y[i]` = `x[i]` + a uniformly random number from `-a` to `a`

`a` is defined as follows:

- Let `z = max(x) - min(x)`
- If `amount==0`, `a = factor * z/50`
- If `amount` is `NULL` or the , `a = factor * d/5` where `d = min(diff(sort(unique(x))))`, i.e., the smallest difference between adjacent unique values.
- Otherwise, `a = amount`.

---

Add test cases

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Does this add anything beyond already existing challenges?

Answer (score 0):

## Output your place

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

---

Your challenge is simple. Output your program's place as an integer at the time of execution. The shortest program is first place, and the earlier submission wins a tie.

If your solution is tied with another in age as well as length, you may output either

All answers must begin with `# [Language Name], [N] bytes` alone on the first line.

You may access this page (URL). No URL shorteners are allowed. Standard [IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884) and [loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) rules hold.

As you may have noticed, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins. Happy golfing!

Comment: This will be very hard to test, no? So each program needs to find "its" post or at least have its own byte count and time stamp hard-coded?

Comment: @Adám Correct. It'll be interesting to see how those two approaches fare, I hope.

Comment: You might want to specify 1 indexing for clarity.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic `The shortest program is first place` was meant to specify that. Too subtle?

Comment: Ah I thought that was intended to say that it was [tag:code-golf].  I think it is likely clear.

Comment: [0 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwQA), output is 0 indexed. or [0 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8//DwQA), outputs via exit code

Comment: @JoKing I thought of that. Some minutes searching TIO yielded nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: From experience, questions like this need to be very explicit about what assumptions can be made about the context in which the answers are executed, because otherwise there will be debates on whether JS programs can execute in the console of a browser window which is currently open on the page.

Answer (score 0):

### Buffer Evaluation

Given a printable ASCII string, but with leading spaces(0x20) and backspaces(0x08), return it "buffer-evaluated".

### Input

For the inputted line, if you encounter a space, enter a space; otherwise, remove the rightmost character.

If you encounter a backspace when the buffer is empty, simply do nothing.

### Output

After the inputted program, if the cursor is 0, output an optional trailing newline. If the cursor is not 0, output the string in the buffer and an optional trailing newline.

### [Example(s) and expected output](https://tio.run/##Sy82@v//Uc9qIFJQUACTunZAlgIXiFCAyEAQUJwLWUjXjuv/fwA)

### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); the shortest answer wins.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Please avoid [adding unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319) like a [cumbersome I/O format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/43319) which just serves to [make the challenge *appear* to be about](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/43319) layout when it is really just simple summing.

Comment: This might be more interesting if there was no such thing as a negative buffer, and backspacing while at `0` did nothing, meaning it isn't just a simple sum of list anymore

Comment: @JoKing Good idea. Or maybe: *Given a printable ASCII string, but with leading spaces and backspaces, return it "evaluated". E.g. `"⌫⌫   ⌫hi"` gives `"  hi"`*

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164449/take-cr-and-lf-literally)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52946/76162), but not taking into account backspacing empty text. I don't like the special case of `0`, since logically, the output should be an empty string, not a backspace

Comment: Regarding 0 → BS: Please avoid [exceptional edge cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17611/43319).

Comment: Many languages will put a trailing line break after the output, further serving to indicate the the process has been completed.

Comment: Your "Output " section seems to be a leftover from the previous version of the challenge: *return it* vs *output how many*

Answer (score 0):

## Crossing Sequences

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189857/crossing-sequences).

Answer (score 0):

## A triangle is worth a thousand lines

[Vulkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)) is a relatively new cross-platform graphics API which is very powerful yet extremely verbose and detailed.

Arguably one of the most infamous saying on Vulkan, especially among beginners is, "The 1000 Lines journey". That is, getting a simple triangle to render on the screen takes a ton of code (~1k lines of C/C++).

**It's time to break, nay, golf the stigma!**

## Challenge

Your challenge is writing a valid Vulkan-API based program which outputs a triangle to the screen. The windowing system is up to your choice as well as the colors/size of the triangle/screen itself.

The final script/compiled program should be able to be executed (preferably on a platform which does not require extra tools/hardware) and the output made visible in order to count as a valid solution.

## Input

None. (Any if you require it, but it will also account into the score)

## Output

A visible triangle on the screen.
The following rules apply:

1. The color of the triangle and the color of the background should be different.
2. The size of the triangle should be noticeable. That is, any person with healthy eyesight should immediately be able to notice it.

**Note:** The final output triangle must be an actual call to drawing a 3 vertexed mesh and not simply points which render to some 4 pixels on screen.

## Hardware constrains

Since the setup code differs greatly from GPU to GPU, you can assume that all the extensions are supported and that the GPU/driver is capable of executing a valid API call. Namely, input validations aren't mandatory, swapchain is present, queues are optimal, etc...

## Scoring

Standard 1 (source code) byte = 1 point scoring, less is better.
(The shaders source file sizes also counts towards the final score)

**Note** There are currently but a few available bindings for Vulkan which means that the language choice isn't as wide as other challenges. However, there is plenty to choose from with different paradigms, thus it shouldn't harm the creativity of the solutions :)

## Helpful resources

- [Language bindings](http://www.vinjn.com/awesome-vulkan/#bindings)
- [Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/#apispecs)
- [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) (Vulkan's predecessor) and a [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/) for it (mainly because it explains some of the aspects in much less code)
- [GLSL specifications](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/), the language which defines the source code of the shaders used.

Comment: Could you perhaps add a link to the Vulcan API in your challenge description? It's personally the first time I heard about it, and had to google a bit. From what I could see the Vulkan API can be used either in C or C++, with no other languages supported, is that correct? In that case this challenge could be tagged: [code-golf]; [c]; [c++]; [graphical-output]; [geometry].

Comment: Sure! also, there are more than a few bindings for Vulkan already available, some even in "glofy" languages, such as lua and haskell: http://www.vinjn.com/awesome-vulkan/#bindings, I'll add some helpful links and directions in the challenge.

Comment: "The size and color don't matter as long as they are different." I think I got your point, but could you rephrase it a bit? I think you mean that the color should be different from the screen's, but I'm not 100% sure, could be "from a run to another run, the triangle has to be different (random size and color)". Plus, if you take this sentence out of context, it has no sense, as seen at start of this comment :)

Comment: Yes I can see how it may seem unclear. What I meant was much more straightforward, "the background and the triangle color should be different" + The triangle itself should be visible too (A normal healthy human eye can see). The intent was clearing two loopholes: 1) Triangle and background are in the same color (Presenting a blank screen as an answer "It's a blue triangle on a blue background"). 2) Rendering a triangle which is too small to see without additional tools
I'm not really sure how to formulate these to be honest..

Answer (score 0):

## Do X without Y

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)
The goal is drawing an X on an empty 3x3 raster "canvas". You have to do so by drawing pixel by pixel, showing each intermediate step. But there should never be an Y visible along the way.

#### Details

- You should start by outputting a 3x3 image of one background color. In each step one of the pixels must be changed to the foreground color.
- You can use any two colors.
- Instead of using pixels in an image, you can also use a string- (leading/trailing zeros/newlines are ok) or 2d-array/matrix representation.
- An X is represented as follows:

```
o.o  (o = foreground, . = background)
.o.
o.o
```

while an `y` can be any of the following

```
o.o  o.o  ..o  o..  
.o.  .o.  .o.  .o.
o..  ..o  o.o  o.o
```

([title reference](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/24877))

Comment: May we also toggle a foreground color back to a background color later on? I.e. would for example these steps be allowed (note the top-middle 'color'): (start:) `... ... ...` > `o.. ... ...` > `oo. ... ...` > `ooo ... ...` > `ooo .o. ...` > `ooo .o. o..` > `ooo .o. o.o` > (end/X:) `o.o .o. o.o`? Also, does the `X` have to be visible in the foregound color, or may it also be in the background color? I.e. would for example these steps be allowed: (start): `ooo ooo ooo` > `o.o ooo ooo` > `o.o .oo ooo` > `o.o .o. ooo` > (end/X:) `o.o .o. o.o`?

Comment: Remind me to upvote this question when it's posted; the title is just awesome

Comment: Wouldn't this work: `1.2 .5. 3.4` (`... ... ...` > `o.. ... ...` > `o.o ... ...` > `o.o ... o..` > `o.o ... o.o` > `o.o .o. o.o`)?

Comment: -1. I don't think there's enough room for variance here. It basically reduces to a Kolmogorov complexity problem that is pretty simple in itself.

Comment: @tjjfvi Yes that would work.

Comment: @Beefster I agree, as it is now it also felt a little bit too restricted. I honestly just wanted to come up with something silly to justify the title:)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That is an interesting extension. I think it would indeed make sense to abolish the idea of foreground/background and just have two colors, and letting people toggle back and forth as many times as they want.

Comment: If the two things I asked in my comment aren't allowed, @tjjfvi approach is the only one possible (in any order of the corners of course) from what I can see, so maybe it's indeed good to allow both to have at least some variance in the challenge approaches. Although I guess most people would use either the one posted by _tjjfvi_ being five steps or the second one I posted being four steps anyway. :)

Comment: Could also have the answers take input of the starting pixels and/or the canvas size.

Comment: idea: what if this were expanded to some sort of fractal/recursive version? You could specify an integer between, say, 0 and 9, and create X's out of X's recursively to that depth, but with the restriction that you can't ever create a Y out of any 5 evenly spaced pixels.

Answer (score 0):

## Get the number of upvotes of your own answer

Write a piece of code which makes a request to `codegolf.stackexchange.com` and prints the, up to date, number of upvotes to **the specific** answer in which you've posted that piece of code.

As a test case I'll post a (poor!) answer below (obviously only in the real question).

This is just a random idea I had when reading some other code golfing challenges, and I thought I'll post it here to see if it will fly.

Comment: Standard procedure(although weird, it is inevitable): Post a placeholder answer, copy the URL, and then make a request to that URL. (Although how can I access the number of votes?)

Comment: Yes, it would inevitably involve editing your answer (unless you embed a unique string in your answer just to find it...?). I admittedly have not tested this yet. I’ll have a play in python and make sure it’s not too hard to extract the information about the number of upvotes...

Comment: I recognise this would be a longer than usual challenge for core golf, but I thought exactly that would maybe make it interesting.

Comment: Can you define "core golf"?

Comment: I'm afraid [it's already done before 3 years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82609/stack-exchange-vote-counter), so it would be closed as a duplicated.

Comment: Thank you for using the Sandbox and finding out it was a duplicate rather than posting it on main first.

Comment: No worries. I came up with it all by myself so I’m still happy. ;) Also, @A__ “core golf” was, of course, a typo.

Answer (score 0):

## Breaking the Wordbuilder (canned)

Dupe of [Let's Play Countdown!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38233/lets-play-countdown) ... oh well. Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Comment: Does the dictionary have to be encoded in submissions, or may they take it as input?

Comment: Take it as input. Assume `unix-words` is a local file.

Comment: similar question.. [Solve an Anagram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127243/solve-an-anagram),  this one is possibly a bit easier

Comment: can languages without file io take `unix-words` as input?

Comment: @SuperStormer, sure thing

Comment: So the two differences between this and [that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127243/solve-an-anagram) are that the input is always precisely five characters long and output words can leave out one or two of them. I'm not really sure if this is a duplicate, but it's close

Comment: The line about the standard loopholes seems to be a bit misleading - the standard loopholes do not ban built-ins that solve the problem. They primarily ban abusive an uninteresting answers like `print("an anagram solver")`. I'm not sure exactly what you want, but it certainly isn't to allow all loopholes. Unrelatedly, the other challenge included multi-word solutions, so I doubt that answers to either can be trivially used for the other without being highly uncompetitive.

Comment: Thanks @FryAmTheEggman, restored the anti-loophole rule.

Comment: A closer previous question is [Let's play countdown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38233/194). IMO the change from 9 input letters to 5 is completely trivial, and the change in the filtering is still sufficiently trivial to count as a dupe.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, you are correct! I'll take this down 

Answer (score 0):

## Break it up and put it back together again

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

**Note:** This is [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source), so read carefully and make sure your answer is valid before posting.

Write a program/function that takes a list of integers greater than 1 and returns a list of *positive* integers where each number from the original list has been split in two. For example:

```
[10,11,12] -> [5,5,4,7,6,6]
```

Each pair of numbers in the output add up to the corresponding number in the input. The algorithm used to split it up doesn't matter (for example a valid output could be `[1,9,1,10,1,11]`), as long as it is deterministic.

**However**, when fed its own byte values and the output is turned back into bytes, the resulting program should do the opposite, taking a list of integers and summing each pair. For example, if the program `abcde` splits each number into halves, with the leftover going to the second number:

```
"abcde" -> [97, 98, 99, 100, 101]
-> [48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51] -> "0111122223"
```

The program `0111122223` should then be able to take the list `[48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51]` and return the original `[97, 98, 99, 100, 101]`

#### Notes/Rules

- Output must be deterministic
- Output can't be a list of lists (no list of pairs)
- The second program may assume that the length of the input is even (so you don't need to account for a leftover element)
- Submissions can be functions, programs or different for either part
- Remember, output must be a list of *positive* integers.

  - You won't get `1` in the input of the first program
- The programs have to be in the same language
- Input can be a string or list of characters instead

Comment: Knowing that low (<32) and high (>127) bytes in most languages are useless or cause errors, it will be difficult to use any lowercase letters in the second program, which might be a problem for case sensitive languages. Braces are nearly impossible without using the high bit, '{' and '}' are 123 and 125, and the maximum ascii value is 126. Not necessarily deal breakers, but important to know.

Comment: Can the two programs be in different languages?

Comment: @Hiatsu I knew I had forgotten to specify something. No, they can't

Answer (score 0):

## Approaching the Graham's number [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Write a program that could theoretically output an integer with the minimum absolute difference to the Graham's number. Your code is cracked if a robber writes a program to output the Graham's number exactly, in the same language, with the edit distance to your code under a specific limit.

Builtins for the Graham's number is disallowed.

Details to be added, if I think this idea actually works.

---

Problems:

How to set the limit?

1. Fixed number of bytes.
2. Fixed % of the code. Does the boilerplate count?
3. Set by the cop. But how to fix the winning criterion?

Do the cops need to know a crack to make the submission valid?

Comment: What does "could theoretically output an integer with the minimum absolute difference..." mean? Would a program that outputs "Hello, World!" in a loop be valid, assuming enough time and radiation? Would a program that outputs all odd numbers be valid? Do we just have to output *any* number?

Comment: @someone "Output an integer" means to output a string matching /-?[0-9]+/ exactly, or any equivalents in other allowed formats. No hello world or multiple numbers. I'm not sure why you would think that.

Answer (score 0):

### Golfed User-Pinging

In this task, given a user's display name(e.g. Display Name) from which the first space has been removed, use the API to find a user it could be and output their display name up to the first space. Both input and output must have an @ prefixed to them.

The input will not contain spaces in it, so you have to search for the user before doing this.

If the user does not exist, do anything else other than outputting the golfed user ping. (That includes outputting to stderr.)

### Rules

- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer wins.
- No standard loopholes allowed. (In fact, hard-coding the answers will annoy other users, as you pinged all of them.)
- The space (U+0020) is the word separator.
- Input will not contain display names containing 2 or more spaces.
- In addition to golfing the code, the answers also have to use as few calls as possible. (Due to the rate limiting of the API)
- The input will always be case-insensitive and are restricted to printable ASCII.

  ### Examples

```
@Dennis -> @Dennis
@MartinEnder -> @Martin
@Cowsquack -> @Cows
@JB -> @J
@tsh -> @tsh
@cairdcoinheringaahing -> @caird
```

---

### Sandbox

- Is it a duplicate?
- Do you understand everything here?
- Any suggestions for test cases?
- Most importantly, **can you cheat over this challenge by using an algorithm not requiring network access?**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)[stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

Comment: Pings don't work like this. Maybe you can instead phrase the challenge as "given a CGCC comment mention (`@username`), reduce it to the first word of the CGCC username it refers to". Also, [tag:internet] is a better tag than [tag:networking] for here. Finally, what happens when the the ping/mention can refer to more than one user?

Comment: This is underspecified. It needs an unambiguous way of determining the word separation.

Comment: 1. I overlooked that this was supposed to be a [tag:stack-exchange-api] question. That should be made explicit. 2. Since it's an API question, it would be best to use the same terminology as the API: i.e. *display name* instead of *username*. 3. If space (U+0020) is the word separator, make that explicit. It seems the TL;DR would be "*Given a user's display name from which the first space has been removed, use the API to find a user it could be and output their display name up to the first space. Both input and output must have an @ prefixed to them.*"

Comment: 4. Making potentially 30+ calls to the API per input is going to make this hard to test without running foul of the rate limiting, so I would suggest explicitly requiring the answers to use as few calls as possible. 5. What about case? If the match should be case-insensitive, either the input should be restricted to ASCII or the way StackExchange handles case conversions should be explicitly documented. The former option seems preferable, because otherwise it randomly boosts languages with default behaviour which matches and penalises those which don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Random point on a sphere

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191510/random-point-on-a-sphere)

Comment: Must we use a specific distribution (e.g. uniform or normal) or is the "bias" acceptable?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer My intention was to require a strictly uniform distribution. I do realize that it is unreasonable to verify this for each and every submission, so I have not made up my mind about that yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm in favor of just using the community default for randomness, that is, if every possible output (up to precision limits) has a non-zero probability of being returned, the submission is valid.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That sounds like a decent compromise. I'll update the challenge.

Comment: Hm... another thing I noticed is that you have 6 tags, you can't have more than 5.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I was unaware of that. I'm removing number-theory, since it is the least fitting.

Comment: Also, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Pick three uniform random numbers and normalise? I think it would be a more interesting question with the requirement that if the random number generation were substituted with true RNG from the reals then the distribution would be uniform. That opens up a [variety of approaches](//mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Comment: @PeterTaylor That was my original intention and I agree that it would definitely be more interesting. However, I thought it might be tricky to verify the uniformity of the distribution for each submission. Your reference could help with that, though.

Comment: I seem to remember a similar challrnge about uniformly generating random numbers that add up to the input, but I can't find it. Not that this is a duplicate, just related

Comment: The challenge as it stands is impossible.  Since there are more real numbers than finite binary strings you cannot represent real numbers in the output of a program.  It is going to be impossible to create a program that has a chance of outputting all the real numbers on the surface of a sphere.  You likely need to restrict the output domain in some way.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic You're correct, I've updated it. Is it more clear like this?

Comment: @JoKing perhaps [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165043/random-numbers-with-fixed-sum)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Since your comment has received quite some upvotes, I have reverted the challenge back to requiring a uniform distribution. I included some examples of how to achieve this. Do you think it is clear enough like this?

Comment: I think it's preferable to talk about being "*theoretically uniform*": to achieve actual uniformity "*up to the precision limits of your language*" would probably require using intermediate values of greater precision. Finding the right wording for questions which use floating point numbers is hard!

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, it's not as trivial as I expected it to be. I guess that's what the sandbox is for. I rephrased the challenge and put more emphasis on the theoretical uniformity.

Comment: In your second and third remarks, it would be good to point out that the random numbers in these invalid schemes are *uniform*.  As shown in the fourth remark, both schemes are valid with specific non-uniform distributions.

Comment: @Nitrodon Excellent point, I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

## "Condense" String of Text

You will be given a string. You will be "condensing" it by combining the bits of characters into one.

### Rules

- The condensation works as follows:

  1. You are given a string with 8-bit characters, such as `Hèl¹ò Wôrld`, hex `48 e8 6c b9 f2 20 57 f4 72 6c 64`
  2. Combines bits into 16-bit groups, from right to left. Above becomes hex `48 e86c b9f2 2057 f472 6c64`, or `H槲⁗汤`.
- You may assume that all characters in string range from `0x00` to `0xff`.
- Your resulting string would be encoded in UTF-16.

  - You may also assume that the resulting string won't contain characters from `0xd800` to `0xdfff`, or the input containing any of `ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß` at even index in 0-index, or odd index in 1-index.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is `code-golf` so shortest code wins.

### Examples

```
Input raw: abacaba
Input hex: 61 62 61 63 61 62 61
Outpt raw: a扡捡扡
Outpt hex: 61 6261 6361 6261
```

```
Input raw: Example.
Input hex: 45 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e
Outpt raw: 䕸慭灬攮
Outpt hex: 4578 616d 706c 652e
```

```
Input raw: ÿ!0ÿMÿEÿSÿSÿAÿGÿE0ÿCÿAÿN0ÿAÿPÿPÿEÿAÿR0ÿTÿOÿOÿ
Input hex: ff 21 30 00 ff 4d ff 45 ff 53 ff 53 ff 41 ff 47 ff 45 30 00 ff 43 ff 41 ff 4e 30 00 ff 41 ff 50 ff 50 ff 45 ff 41 ff 52 30 00 ff 54 ff 4f ff 4f ff 0e
Outpt raw: Ａ　ｍｅｓｓａｇｅ　ｃａｎ　ａｐｐｅａｒ　ｔｏｏ．
Outpt hex: ff21 3000 ff4d ff45 ff53 ff53 ff41 ff47 ff45 3000 ff43 ff41 ff4e 3000 ff41 ff50 ff50 ff45 ff41 ff52 3000 ff54 ff4f ff4f ff0e
Note that there are NULs in the input.
```

Comment: You might want to specify an encoding for the 16-bit encoding. For example, if you use UTF-16, then the values `D800`-`DFFF` are not valid characters

Comment: This is essentially translation between encoding types, since the input bytes will be identical to the output bytes

Answer (score 0):

**Self-fibonaciing prophecy**

Where `L` is the length in bytes of your source code
and `n=(L+2)^2`

Your program or function should output `Fib(n)`

Your program or function should take no input, and output according to the usual code golf rules

This seems like a very simple task, but the `(L+2)^2` part is designed to prevent single digit outputs which could be hard coded in many languages, and ensure the required output will usually be longer than the source code, so it should produce some interesting mathematical answers

Question for meta - Is `(L+2)^2` suitable for this?
Another possibility I have considered is `(L^2)+8` which would grow a bit slower but still achieve the goal of preventing trivial solutions
Having a look at this again, I think the sequence still grows too quickly. Maybe `n=ceil(L^1.5)+18` would be more reasonable

Another question for meta - Should I include a link to a source of Fibonaci numbers, or is it safe to assume readers know what this is and can find it for themselves?

Comment: It probably isn't exactly necessary to explain the Fibonacci sequence, but I think it would be better if you did. You should explicitly state what you consider to be valid initial points (i.e. is `Fib(0), Fib(1) = 0, 1` acceptable? I'm not sure about the scaling sequence, but I do think your idea for preventing too many trivial answers is a good one. You might consider just doing `L+100` since that should probably make hardcoding inefficient but make calculation much easier.

Comment: The point of `(L+2)^2` or whatever other function seems to be to push answers towards actually implementing a general-purpose Fibonacci function, but that makes the question a dupe of the [general-purpose Fibonacci question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/194). I don't see how this can be rescued: either it's a dupe, or it's possible to "cheat".

Comment: @Peter Taylor Here `Fib(n)` is a number that depends only on the program length but not any other input. It is unnecessary to implement a general purpose Fibonoacci function at all. You can just print a Fibonoacci number and tune the length of the program to fit the requirement.

Comment: @JoKing `print(34)` is 7 bytes, which would require to output a 9 digit number not a 2 digit number. If you simply change the 34 for the required 9 digit number, then your solution becomes 14 bytes, so would then require to output a 15 digit number rather than 9, and so on. The output is always longer than your source code, hence trival answers are by design, not possible

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman the `L+100` idea seems promising, but I fear it would then open up to trival answers for high L, indeed JoKing's point would then run true for `L>33`. I feel the function needs some kind of exponent to eliminate that problem

Comment: Ah oops, I missed that part and thought it was just `Fib(length)`.  Still, it's then going to be either base compression for golfier languages, or just indexing into the fibonacci list at the correct index

Comment: @Joel, I said "*push towards*" not "*absolutely require*". The key points are: (1) if it's competitive to tweak an answer from the general-purpose Fibonacci question, this is a dupe; (2) if it isn't then setting `n=(L+2)^2` would seem not to have done its job.

Comment: @Peter Taylor I see your point. However, since the problem does not require to output the entire Fibonacci sequence, it is allowed to use any function to generate a single Fibonacci number that fits the requirement. There might be a non-trivial solution that is shorter than a general-purpose Fibonacci function implementation.

Comment: I'm mostly curious about the calculation of `n`, I want to design it in such a way that it prevents trival answers, as my goal with this challenge is to see some interesting calculations. Trivial answers for very low L or very high L will be possible with a poorly chosen formula. This might even be a question for math.se

Comment: After some further research and experimentation, I'm considering using `n=(L+2)*5` this is the slowest growing formula I have found so far that fits the requirements

Answer (score 0):

## Compare Multiratios

EDIT: No doesn't make any sense, I need to think about it again.

Answer (score 0):

## Smallest self-hosting golfing language [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Implement a golfing language that is implemented in itself. Formally speaking: The original compiler O (an executable file assumed to be implemented in other language X), when given its own source code S (in golfing language G), must produce the identical executable file O. Your task is to create G by implementing O.

Language X might be an ELF binary, x86 assembly, Python, LLVM IR, etc.

Neither your language implementation S or executable file O may use functions that have the same functionality as exec or eval. That is, you may not use any built-in code evaluation of your compiler O. Standard Quine loopholes, such as reading your own file, downloading your file from the internet, and holding the program data in the filename, are not allowed.

The executable file O of the compiler must not be embedded in any shape or form in the source code S of the compiler. Additionally, the source code S of the compiler must be strictly shorter than the executable file O.

Your code must not be dependent on any external program or internet resource other than language X: if your language is dependent, include the size of the external dependencies in your submissions. Your program gets a standard POSIX system base for free, plus GCC 8 and LLVM 10: you do not have to include the size of this in your submission. For example, if you submitted a Bash Quine that just invoked the 05AB1E interpreter via the command line, you would have to include both the size of the the 05AB1E implementation, as well as the size of the Elixir implementation (since 05AB1E is implemented in Elixir and your base language X isn’t Elixir) in your bytecount.

In addition, standard golfing loopholes apply.

## Requirements

Answer at least 10 other [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges on this website, beating at least 50% of the existing answers in byte size.

- Only challenges that already have 4 answers are allowed
- Your own other answers to the challenges do not count
- Challenges newer than this post are allowed, as well as answering your own challenges; provided they already have 4 answers from other answerers
- Link to your challenge answers for verification

### Base language X restrictions

Language X must have an implementation, in other words we must be able to actually run your compiler O with source code S and get compiler O as output.

Language X must have already existed before this post was created.

You are encouraged to share the techniques of how you created your compiler and how you came up with your golfing language.

### Scoring

$$S*0.98^{(n-10)}$$ where n is the number of challenges where you beat at least 50% of the other answers, not including your own.

---

## Feedback

How can you prevent someone submit a zero bytes answer and claim: if source is empty, it output the interpreter, otherwise output compiled python code. – tsh Aug 24 at 4:42

Comment: I don't think your requirements are a good way to handle making people use a real language. It doesn't do much to prevent abuse and is extremely tedious to perform and to verify. I'm sorry I don't have an alternative, but I think that may be a red flag that this won't work very well on this site.

Comment: Is there a reason languages created after this is posted are not eligible?

Comment: It may be worth explicitly stating that lowest wins in the scoring section.

Answer (score 0):

## DRAFT: Remove vertical comments [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Vertical commnets...

```
        /> push back with    result.cows_used.push_back(possiblecow);
        the new cow added </ cows_used.push_back(result.cows_used);
```

Traditional comments...

```
        /* push back with */ result.cows_used.push_back(possiblecow);
     /* the new cow added */ cows_used.push_back(result.cows_used);


        result.cows_used.push_back(possiblecow);
        cows_used.push_back(result.cows_used);
```

Annotated, everything with . is considered a comment:

```
        />.................. result.cows_used.push_back(possiblecow);
        ..................</ cows_used.push_back(result.cows_used);
```

What is both between the start row of /= and the end row of =/ and between the start column of /= and the end column of =/ is considered a comment.

```
        /> push back with       result.cows_used.push_back(possiblecow);
           the new cow added </ cows_used.push_back(result.cows_used);
```

---

## Todo

- Add testcases

Comment: Can vertical comments be nested or overlapped?

Comment: Will this language have string literal?

Answer (score 0):

## I see your BIDMAS and raise you a BADMIS

### Challenge

Given a set of numbers with operators between them: "5 + 4 * 9 / 3 - 8", return all the possible results of the expression for every permutation of the order of basic operations: [/, *, +, -].

### Rules

- Standard loopholes forbidden
- I/O

  - Input must be ordered with infix operations, but however that is easiest (string or array)
  - Output must be all of the possible results of the expression, no specified format or order, no repeats
- All of the inputs are valid (e.g. do not need to deal with "7 / 3 + *"
- Operators are all left-associative so "20 / 4 / 2" = "(20 / 4) / 2"
- This is Code Golf so fewest number of bytes wins

### Test Cases (With explanation)

- "2 + 3 * 4" = [14, 20]

  - 2 + (3 * 4)  ⟶  2 + (12) ⟶ 14
  - (2 + 3) * 4 ⟶ (5) * 4 ⟶ 20
- "18 / 3 * 2 - 1" = [11, 6, 2, 6]

  - ((18 / 3) * 2) - 1 ⟶ ((6) * 2) - 1 ⟶ (12) - 1 ⟶ 11
  - ((18 / 3) * (2 - 1) ⟶ (6) * (1) ⟶ 6
  - (18 / (3 * 2)) - 1 ⟶ (18 / (6)) - 1 ⟶ (3) - 1 ⟶ 2
  - 18 / (3 * (2 - 1)) ⟶ 18 / (3 * (1)) ⟶ 6

### Test Cases (Without explanation)

- "45 / 8 + 19 / 45 * 3" = [5.765740740740741, 0.01234567901234568, 0.11111111111111113]
- "2 + 6 * 7 * 2 + 6 / 4" = [154,113.5,88]

Comment: I'd recommend removing the bonus part, since people aren't going to do more than they have to, especially if it's [tag:code-golf] (which I'm assuming this is, though you haven't specified it)

Comment: An I/O question: would providing `45 / 8` as `45.0 / 8.0` to the program be allowed? I suggest allowing it. This frees users working in languages which parse integers as integer types by default to work on the problem you ask, instead of an ancillary problem.

Comment: @GammaFunction Yes that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

## The Rattlin' Bog

There's a relatively famous Irish Folk song called *The Rattlin' Bog*, a type of [cumulative song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_song).

Basically, this is a song that alternates between a chorus and an ever-expanding verse

The chorus is as follows:

*Ho, ro, the rattlin' bog

The bog down in the valley-o

Ho, ro, the rattlin' bog

The bog down in the valley-o*

Each verse starts with
*And on that [x] there was a [y]

A rare [y], a rattlin' [y]*

and ends with
*In the bog down in the valley-o*

Where x is the word from the previous round, and y is the word for the current round. In between these two is the cumulative part. It starts with:
*The [z] in the bog*

Each new round adds
*The [y] in the [x] and* 
To its predecessor.

#### Challenge

Given a list of strings, character arrays, or whatever reasonable equivalent collection of string or your language equivalent thereof, Your job is to print the lyrics to the song, alternating between the chorus and each verse, starting and ending with the chorus. The chorus and verse must be separated by a pair of newlines.

For the sake of brevity, you may write the chorus once, preceded by "[Chorus]" then write "[Chorus]" in place. I'm also omitting any sort of final verse with unique text.

**Example:**

```
Input: [House, Roof, Nest] 
Output:
[Chorus] 
Ho, ro, the rattlin' bog 
The bog down in the valley-o 
Ho, ro, the rattlin' bog 
The bog down in the valley-o  

And on that bog there was a House
A rare House, a rattlin' House
The House in the bog
In the bog down in the valley-o

[Chorus]

And on that House there was a Roof
A rare Roof, a rattlin' Roof
The Roof in the House and the House in the bog
In the bog down in the valley-o

[Chorus]

And on that Roof there was a Nest
A rare Nest, a rattlin' Nest
The Nest in the Roof and the Roof in the House and the House in the bog
In the bog down in the valley-o

[Chorus]
```

Comment: I'm terrible at formatting, so if anyone wants to tell me the best formatting for this or edit and reformat it, that's fine. Of course, feedback is also appreciated to make this more readable or easier to understand. Also if/when I put it up on main golf, i'll add the standard disclaimers about abusing loopholes and least bytes wins, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding input is enough to make a difference between this and something like [There was an Old Lady](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3697/42963) or [There's a hole in the bottom of the sea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179269/42963)...

Answer (score 0):

## Sliding window minimum [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)

The task is, given a number array of length `n` and a positive integer `k`, to compute the smallest values in all its overlapping consecutive subarrays of length `k` in the order they occur.

The complexity of your program should be no more than linear with respect to `n` with a constant added.

## Input

A positive integer array of length `n` and a positive integer `k` (`k <= n`)

## Output

A positive integer array with `n - k + 1` elements, where the element at position `i` equals the least number in the subarray starting at `i` and ending at `i + k - 1` inclusive.

## Examples

```
[1, 3, 5, 7], 2 -> [1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1], 3 -> [1, 3, 3, 1]
```

TODO

## Sandbox stuff

- Is it acceptable to combine code-golf with restricted-complexity?
- Is the complexity restriction clear enough?
- Is it a good idea to allow calculating the maximum instead of the mininum?
- Is the grammar correct enough?
- Has this been posted before?
- Do any languages have built-ins for this?

Comment: [Close to a dupe.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118210/all-the-k-mers-n-grams/152005?r=SearchResults&s=7|26.1473#152005) This one adds the minimum operation; you don't need to modify the programs in that question too much in order to post submissions for this challenge.

Comment: @A_ I'm perfectly certain it's not, that one doesn't have [restricted-complexity].

Comment: This functionality is needed in statistical analysis so I think many statistics / data analysis oriented languages or libraries would have a built-in for it. For example, [this is the built-in](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caTools/versions/1.17.1/topics/runmin%20%26%20runmax) in the R language.

Comment: Meanwhile, the complexity of the function depends also on k. So "linear with respect to n with a constant added" might not be accurate enough without mentioning k. It would be better to say sth. like "linear with respect to n for each fixed value of k".

Comment: @Joel Are you sure? I think I can compute it with a deque in O(n + k), and since k <= n that is linear with respect to n.

Comment: A basic deque-based approach needs O(k) time to calculate or updating the minimum for each window in the worst case so the overall worse-case complexity would be O(n + k(n - k)) which is the same as O(n + kn). If you use a priority queue the complexity can be driven down to O(n+nlogk) or maybe O(n) only for some very advanced implementations. How do you implement that in O(n + k)?

Comment: @Joel [reference O(n) implementation by me](https://tio.run/##rVLRboIwFH2mX3HnEoWhU8c2E0V@xJGFlSoVbLFUzbL47e62oI5lvu0BenvO6em5N6VlOVhRejrdc0GLXcog5LLSiiWbiFyxlG137CeQFCupuM5aqj2jWqqIcKFhk3DhmiJRK9oHmiXqAcv9IvbIF3EMo2dQ6XQ6pVxAFOGWOIeMF8zVMBhEMPKIg0orFX3I22r7y/GIY9H66hC1EWDtCs9QS6lsBg5zGM1wCUHg4vteywsPLHh88bLN1lbp1s1vOeW1E5ImZRP9Lt0@sk2pP10Put3GGcK5rZD7SGjuerE55Ti4L2X5XmPmFovsqqyGuMWOf7WYiMoVMIAcfBhbmQm3rsMNh0gfmIJSIsrUr/h5axDn@Hhksfb9GC5Rl0oKjVlnN7u7ikyH3ORpNdaQJpGWEmSR/sugGrtqkxTFraEBaVr6u6Ebb@M80cto6slTudMQhmbqNmQIHehcnsuZ7b2JHoJHcjydAvIMT2QMAbzAxNYTrAIYk1cIGtx8428 "Try It Online")

Comment: @someone OK. That algorithm is O(n). So you may emphasize in the description to say "The complexity of your program should be O(n), i.e. linear with respect to n for every possible k <= n", in case anyone wonders about whether an O(n + nlogk) implementation is accepted.

Comment: @Joel I'd argue O(n log k) is not really linear with respect to n (since that equals O(n log n))

Comment: @someone O(nlogk) is not linear with respect to n but it is also different from O(nlogn) because it really depends on the input k. If k has another constraint itself (e.g. an upper bound that is better than O(n)), O(nlogk) could be better than O(nlogn). That is why I suggested you clearly mention about the range of k in the complexity description to avoid any possible confusion, as I showed in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Universal duct tape programming [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [duct-tape-coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duct-tape-coding) [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot)

The task is to write a program that [TODO: insert simpleish task here] that works in as many languages as possible, while only using code that was already written before by someone else at http://stackoverflow.com.
To minimize time, you are trying to use as few snippets as possible. Therefore, they must be as long as possible.

Code from http://stackoverflow.com is defined as substrings of code blocks in questions, answers and comments created before this challenge [TODO: or perhaps this sandbox post?]. You must link to the source of the code in your answer.
You can concatenate multiple snippets, optionally inserting newlines.

Your code must work in at least two different languages.

Your score is equal to the minimum of the number of languages your code works in and the length of the shortest snippet you use. Highest score wins.

## Sandbox stuff

- Is this a good idea?
- How simple should the simpleish task be?
- Can the scoring system be abused?
- Does the "multiple languages" part need clarification?
- Does the "stackoverflow snippets" part need clarification?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a polyglot or just multiple versions of the same problem? Why require 2 snippets? I think a better scoring system would be `language_count/number_of_snippets`. The best way to abuse the scoring system right now is to copy from overly verbose languages like Java.

Comment: @Beefster This is supposed to be a polyglot. Will try to fix all 3 points in a few hours.

Comment: Can we use snippets from code review as well?

Comment: -1 duct-taping and polyglotting are mostly incompatible goals. This will tend to result in a lot of C/C++ solutions and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

## Consequence Golf

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golf)

As specified by [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1920/), Consequence Golf is a game involving golfing and bombs. The most obvious consequence of bombs: damage to the course.

A Consequence Golf course consists of the union of several circular regions. The tee is located at (0, 0). On each turn, you hit the <strike>ball</strike> bomb in a direction at some power. The bomb will travel in that direction for a distance equal to the power of the shot, unless it hits the edge of the course, in which case it will explode immediately. When a bomb explodes, it adds to the course a new circle centered on the point of contact with a radius equal to the remaining power. The next shot starts at the last location of the bomb.

#### Input

- A list of circles, consisting of x/y coordinates and a radius for each circle, taken in any convenient format. If you must define a custom data type to store this information (e.g. `struct c{float x,y,r};`), you do not need to count that added *boilerplate, nonproductive storage* code in your byte count. Any code that does something besides specify storage must be counted.
- A list of strokes, consisting of an angle in radians or degrees, and a power, again in any convenient format.

#### Output

- The location of the bomb after the final stroke.

#### Additional Rules

- The course will always contain at least one circle
- The course will always contain the tee at (0, 0)
- If there are zero strokes, you must return (0, 0)
- The power of a stroke will never be zero
- "Any convenient format" means a list of lists, list of C structs, a list for each input (x, y, radius, power, angle), or similar. You may not take information that is not as it is specified. For example, you may not take the circles as a series of equations.
- This is  <strike>consequence</strike> code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

TBD...

> #### Questions for META:
>
> - Is the description of how to play Consequence Golf clear enough?
> - Is the description of the input clear enough? This is my main concern.
> - Is allowing boilerplate storage code outside of the byte count an issue?
> - I am considering allowing fixed point approximations with at least 4 bits of precision for languages without floating point (and languages with, if it somehow makes things shorter). Would this cause any unintended issues?

Comment: The overview talks about the bomb hitting walls, but the input section doesn't include anything about the walls.

Answer (score 0):

Encode MC6000 instructions

In MC6000, these are registers list:

```
acc  general
dat  general
p0   simple pin
p1   simple pin
x0   XBus pin
x1   XBus pin
x2   XBus pin
x3   XBus pin
null pseudo
```

where `general` means reading from it returns the last value written to it, `XBus pin` means reading from or writing to it have side effect(so `teq x0 x1` doesn't equal to `teq x1 x0`) that nothing else can take its place, `simple pin` means reading from it also writes zero to it(so `mov 0 p0` equals to `mov p0 null`), writing anything to it(including the writing while reading) have side effect, and writing anything larger than 100 behaves same as writing 100, as well as writing anything smaller than 0 same as writing 0(so `mov -4 p0` equals to `mov 0 p0`). Writing anything into `null` has no effect and reading from `null` returns 0(so `mov 9 null` equals to `nop`).

The instruction set is:

```
nop            Do nothing
mov R/I R      operand2:=operand1
jmp L          Jump to the specified line(can't be replaced)
slp R/I        Sleep for the number of time units specified by the operand.
slx XP         Sleep until XP avaliable(can't be replaced)
add R/I        acc:=f(acc+operand)
sub R/I        acc:=f(acc-operand)
mul R/I        acc:=f(acc*operand)
not            acc:=100(if acc was 0) or 0(otherwise)
dgt R/I        acc:=(acc/10^operand)mod 10(if operand in 0,1,2) or 0(otherwise)
dst R/I R/I    acc:=[abs(acc-[(acc/10^operand1)mod 10]*10^operand1)+abs(operand2 mod 10)*10^operand1]
               *sgn(operand2*2+1) (if operand1 in 0,1,2) or acc(otherwise)
teq R/I R/I    sym:='+'(if operand1 equals to operand2) or '-'(otherwise)
tgt R/I R/I    sym:='+'(if operand1 is larger than operand2) or '-'(otherwise)
tlt R/I R/I    sym:='+'(if operand1 is smaller than operand2) or '-'(otherwise)
tcp R/I R/I    sym:='+'(if operand1 is larger than operand2),
               '-'(if operand1 is smaller than operand2) or '*'(otherwise)
gen SP R/I R/I Output 100 and 0 to the simple pin for the latter two operands, inclusive
```

Here `R/I` means a register or an integer between -999 and 999, inclusive; `R` means a register, `L` means an integer between 0 and 13, `XP` means an XBus pin, and `SP` means a simple pin. `f(x)` is defined as `min(999,max(-999,x))`. Sleeping for zero or negative time units sleep for time as long as a `nop`(so `nop`=`slp 0`=`slp -3`).

Before an instruction, symbol `+`, `-` and `@` can exist, meaning that the instruction is executed only if sym is `+`, `-` and `@`, inclusive. (`@` doesn't work like this in fact but that doesn't affect this problem) Whether the instruction is executed matters even if it's a no operand(so `+ nop` doesn't equal to `- nop`, but `+ nop` equals to `+ tgt 1 0`).After an instruction, comment start with `#` can exist, which can be ignored. Spaces work as separator, and can be added or removed as long as words are separated in the same way(continious spaces, spaces at both side).

---

Now, write a program A that, reads an instruction and output an integer; and write a program B that reads the output of program A and output an equal or same instruction fed into program A.

Your score will be the sum of length of program A, length of program B, and difference between the maximum and minimum of output of A. Lowest score in every language win.

Using MetaGolfScript is allowed. Only write `MetaGolfScript` in language area and show the exact version you use in code area to make it leaderboard friendly.

Comment: Why do you allow MetaGolfScript? Does it add anything to the challenge apart from a boring winner answer?

Comment: @wastl Pure (difference between the maximum and minimum of output of A) worth optimize

Answer (score 0):

[Posted to PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191559/stage-a-coup-to-become-king-of-the-hill/191560)

Comment: When I first posted this to PPCG, @PeterTaylor pointed out that although outputs to a file are allowed for King of the Hill challenges, it is preferable to use STDIN/STDOUT. But the fundamental problem is that programs need a standard venue, hidden from each other but not from the Arbiter, in order to Exchange.

Comment: If you fail to challenge an assassination, how do you format losing two cards?

Comment: @Hiatsu Assuming you mean "incorrectly challenge" or "get caught falsely blocking with a Contessa", you don't need to. You write the card you lost from the failed challenge, then the Arbiter detects that the move was an Assassination and you are eliminated. But your wording could be interpreted another way: I noticed in your answer to the original challenge that you always challenged or blocked Assassinations. You don't have to do that. You can surrender one of your cards right away.

Comment: As long as each program has its own STDIN/STDOUT (using `player=subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); player.stdin.write("I\n"); response=player.stdout.read(1);` or similar), you can copy across communication from the other player but restrict exchanges to the relevant player.

Comment: Also, if you are willing to translate the Arbiter into Java, you can use [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/introducing-kothcomm-a-framework-for-your-king-of-the-hill-challenges) to arrange games.

Comment: @Hiatsu Done! ...Well, kind of. I gave up and posted the original question. [See my explanation in the comments here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191559/stage-a-coup-to-become-king-of-the-hill/191560#191560)

Answer (score 0):

## Product of Shuffle Algebra

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Compute the shuffle product of two elements of a *Shuffle Algebra*.

### Definitions

1. An *Alphabet* is a set of symbols. For this challenge it is \$A = \{a,b,c,\ldots,z\}\$. Let us use **bold** letters for variables that denote elements of the alphabet.
2. A *Word* is a tuple of of arbitrary size where each entry is an element of our alhpabet. Let \$W\$ be the set of words. Instead of writing a word as \$(p,p,c,g)\$ we just omit the unnecessary symbols and write it as \$ppcg\$. We write the *empty word* as \$\varepsilon = ()\$. Let us use lower case greek letters (\$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots\$) for variables that denote words.
3. The *shuffle algebra* \$S\$ (simplified for the purpose of this challenge) is a set of \$\mathbb Z\$-linear combinations of words. This means that each element consists of a few words which each have an integer associated with them (the *coefficients*), which are then formally summed up. Here are some examples:
   $$\begin{array}[l] \\ a \\ b \\ 5\varepsilon = 5\\ a + (-5)b = a-5b \\ a + 2a = 3a \\xy - 3code +5golf +5se  \end{array}$$
   Note that terms (that is a word with it's coefficient) where the coefficient is zero are considered as \$0\$ and are not listed. Let us use uppercase letters form the greek alphabet (\$ \Gamma, \Delta, \Phi, \Psi, \ldots \$) letters for variables denoting an element of the shuffle algebra.
4. We can add elements of the shuffle algebra just as you'd expect: The coefficients of equal words are just summed.  for instance let
   $$\begin{align*} A &:= aq + 3bccd + 5cg \\B 
   &:= -3bccd + 6cg + 5qq .\end{align*}$$
   Then $$\begin{align*} A+B &= aq + 0bbcd + 11cg + 5qq \\&= aq + 11cg + 5qq.\end{align*}$$
5. We *multiply* elements of the shuffle algebra using the *shuffle product* denoted by the symbol \$⧢\$. We can recursively define it as follows:

   A. First we define the shuffle product for words: if one of the words is empty (=\$\varepsilon\$) we have $$\alpha ⧢ \varepsilon = \varepsilon ⧢ \alpha = \alpha.$$ If both are nonempty, we split them up into a one letter suffix and a leading word. So let us write the two words \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ as $$\alpha = \varphi \mathbf{a} \qquad \beta = \psi \mathbf{b}$$ Then the product is defined via the recursion $$\alpha ⧢ \beta = (\varphi ⧢ \beta)\mathbf{a} +(\alpha ⧢ \psi)\mathbf{b}.$$ This is where the "shuffle" in the name is coming from: The *shuffle product* results in all possible [*riffle shuffles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation) of the two words. Consider the following examples: $$\begin{align*}ab ⧢ xy = abxy + axby + xaby + axyb + xayb + xyab\end{align*}$$

   B. Two shuffle algebra elements \$\Phi = \sum_i f_i \varphi_i \$ and \$\Psi = \sum_j g_j \psi_j \$ (where \$f_i, g_j \in \mathbb Z, \varphi_i, \psi_j \in W\$) are multiplied as follows:
   $$\Phi ⧢ \Psi = \sum_i \sum_j \underbrace{(f_i \cdot g_j)}_{\in \mathbb Z} \underbrace{(\varphi_i ⧢ \psi_j)}_{\in S}$$

#### Details

- The inputs can each be taken as a string or as a list of pairs where each pair is represents one term (coefficient and word) of the element, or alternatively as two lists of the same length or other similar formats.
- The output format must match the input format.
- The output must be reduced: No two terms should share the same word.

#### Examples

[Haskell script for generating Examples](https://tio.run/##fVW5jtswEO35FQNhC9EHsHYprNy5SJNm0zmGlpJGNhEdjkhHWCD/7gxJnZayzS41781wjjf0VahfmOcP/XlD@IF1ASH430qNF6w38K5rWV44S4UWcMyxwFIT4QgnQz1DirX8Qwzwj785k6XSokwQvt@Lnt1csUYGAtYQkys6c6SIIiA2wGoC3OoqvSfagSVehEY6D3hnIs9YWeReppjJElMGSl5KG3hizeqqaEsCOYGGlN@vVfOcszI2n4o9c/LyvMHi@8mm4YFW3CBJhVkG6zX4MoMmDD0P9BVL8qCsFYK38gzacPO3C0G@DLqboI0RAkVI4O21DQBbb/DZJhzagLC2dt8CCWfsqTsuvp3UCxTiBv5PmzFsD@C3nGRDGXHiMaZpmNF4MkHgtED0rifDcU73kx0F2/GhWfTfGMl2/ppOndzTx941k8FfAiAMyQJt@sReWw45BCZd4lTUnrqR1IqO44IQoUalTUNtZwk038T6MgkzCzYBXR1ohRlPIBRDlSievHwRCKMJfJY6uRAAdIxERChr8@sNCxkKczVjtWiipqrTfjNoOG4vzUyG08kdz3MHYZQYwkksYISYy0/xAuaqAT8OYismA6oox0xbOduvWl6umvU6HlFCJzwRUIR5SqoNy3snG6nzihe92oRiMy7brlFLZo@W1fqScSLjPnQvh05Ko@XxN5zwVbLnS1mRYIk/CGiU1Hx5xgk8O7S6itz@nGd4NNmv85K/ndcR3Lx6Mcnilsvsk8rJqjzNd9NXOM@jcSvUMM0Z1Mm0u/Ht5WBG@bY60JWjFeouXGzBnLZc1hhuF8vsfqaMoumJeF0q0fXA8FSZEu/DMD7sGK1BLTlRYxa2bwg1fW4ol9ZTYhpZyui9mUD/z/BRCFkSnFYMbiRNTTnYn8KHaJ9P0qMnYo9vwB49eknjEWSB7W7jpUjQ4x8)

Comment: Might you consider just having the challenge be to multiply two words? When thinking about how I'd do this challenge, I'm imagining implementing the shuffle product, than iterating over pairs of monomials and multiplying them and their coefficients, then reducing by combining like terms. I don't know anything about the shuffle algebra, so I don't know if there's something that lets you work with elements in some more special way.

Comment: @xnor My thought was that if we just take two words for the input, the output will still be a general element (e.g. `aa ⧢ ab = 3*aaab +2*aaba +1*abaa`), so you would already have to implement the simplification (collecting the the terms with the same words), so the additionl step of multiplying two general elements wouldn't be a lot more compilcated. - Would you suggest also removing the simplification step, so that the output would just be a list? (e.g. `aaab,aaab,aaba,aaab,aaba,abaa` for the input from above) I think this would on the one hand be a lot easier, but also less of a challenge.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't considered that a riffle product of monomials would already produce repeats. I don't know what I'd suggest. For what it's worth, I tried searching for a duplicate of generating all possible riffles and didn't find one, though I have a memory of having done something like it on anarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Tiling string

(inspired by the tiling pattern effect tipic of the texturing of landscapes.
This question I would like to ask is not exactly the same thing but close to it, or at least it was the idea)

Given a string S check if it has some repeating tile pattern and prove it providing at least one repeating pattern.

A substring tile pattern is a pattern of any form which repeats inside the string where one or more(alpha case insensitive) chars forms a fixed structure that can contain also others generic chars(all printable ascii table set)

the output will be false,0,f or any meaningful negative expression if no tiling occours.
true,1,... plus at least one repeating tile pattern instead.

for example :

```
 they were obsessed by the sessions
             s#ss          s#ss
 outputs : true s#ss



look at that truck
      t$t  t$t
outputs: 1,t$t


- case insensitive. 
- only letters matters as tile pattern.   
- if two letters are separated by space or every non letter char they still form a pattern.  
- overlaps doesnt make tiling effect.
- a pattern must contain half or more structure chars and must be len>1 to be considered, and must be repeated at least two times.
```

example

"Hello world!"=> false or 0 or f or no

"aa"=>false.
   aaa=>false. 
   "aaaa"=> true(aa)
   "aabbabab"=>true:ab,ba  or 1 ab ba. or yes[ba,ab]
    or...any reasonable format

This is code-golf so shortest answer wins

Comment: Can you give an example of a tile with non-structure characters?

Comment: Hi!ho!bushy! => h#! Here h and ! Form a pattern of 2 fixed symbols and one ?symbol between. But it's not valid as ! is not an alpha character. The same applies to spaces or , or . for example..

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192900/inquiry-answerer)

Comment: So: If input ends with `?` and has `,` return text from last `,` until before `?` Else, if input ends with `?` return `No` Else, return `Yes`. Right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Then maybe just say so instead of over-complicating it?

Answer (score 0):

## Observability and controllability

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

#### Background

*Note: if you like, you can skip this part, and simply implement the suggested algorithm.*

When looking at dynamic systems, there exist the notions of [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability) and [controllability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability). They are the answers to the questions

- Observability: can we know all the internal states of a system by looking only at the given outputs?
- Controllability: can we influence all the internal states of a system by changing only the inputs?

For the sake of this question, we will only look at LTI (linear time-invariant) systems, either in continuous or discrete time. During the rest of the question, I will only present the case of a state-space representation of the system and suggest using the observability- or controllability Gramian, but you may use any other algorithm to decide the controllability and observability of  the given LTI system.

#### Input

You are given an LTI system, $$ \mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = A\mathbf{x}(t) + B\mathbf{u}(t)\\\mathbf{y}(t)=C\mathbf{x}(t)$$ where \$A\$, \$B\$ and \$C\$ are matrices containing only integers. The dimensions of these matrices are \$\dim{A}=n \times n\$, \$\dim{B} = n \times p \$ and \$\dim{C} = q \times n\$ with \$n\$, \$p\$ and \$q\$ positive integers.

A suggested input method would be to simply input these matrices, but you may also take input as function objects, string representations of differential equations, or transfer functions.

#### Output

You must output two thruthy/falsy values, one indicating whether the system is controllable, and one indicating whether the system is observable. Order does not matter but must always be the same. Alternatively, you may have four distinct outputs (e.g., the integers 0, 1, 2, 3) each corresponding to a possible combination of controllability/observability.

#### Suggested algorithm

To decide on observability and controllability, you can calculate the so-called observability Gramian (a square matrix), $$\begin{bmatrix}C & CA & CA^2 & ... & CA^{(n-1)}\end{bmatrix}^T$$ and controllability Gramian $$\begin{bmatrix}B & AB & A^2B & ... & A^{(n-1)}B\end{bmatrix}$$
The system is observable iff the observability Gramian is invertible. The system is controllable iff the controllability Gramian is invertible. [There are many ways to check if a matrix is invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem); an obvious way would be to check if the [determinant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147668/determinant-of-an-integer-matrix) equals zero.

## Testcases

Coming soon, because I want to include worked examples.

Comment: I'm not sure requiring tests for both is particularly meaningful, since an LTI system \$ (A, \cdot ,C) \$ is observable iff the LTI system \$ ( A^{T}, C^{T}, \cdot ) \$ is controllable. Otherwise I think this is fine (though for some reason I thought it had already been asked, but I didn't find a dupe).

Comment: @FryAmEggman True but I think almost-repetition can make golfing challenges interesting because there's so many ways to do that.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for the edits, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

## Reorder a matrix, twice

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)

You are given a square \$n \times n\$ matrix \$A\$, and a list (or vector) \$u\$ of length \$n\$ containing the numbers \$1\$ through \$n\$ (or \$0\$ through \$n-1\$). Your task is to reorder the columns **and** rows of the matrix \$A\$ according to the order specified in \$u\$.

That is, you will construct  a matrix \$B\$ where the \$(i,j)\$-th element is the \$(u(i),u(j))\$-th element of \$A\$. You should also output the inverse of this action; that is, the (i,j)-th element of \$A\$ will end up at position \$(u(i),u(j))\$ in a new matrix \$C\$.

For example, given $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 11 &12& 13 \\ 21& 22& 23 \\ 31& 32& 33 \end{bmatrix},\quad u=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

the output should be $$B = \begin{bmatrix}33 & 31 & 32 \\ 13 & 11 & 12 \\ 23 & 21 & 22 \end{bmatrix},\quad C= \begin{bmatrix}22 & 23 & 21 \\32 & 33 & 31 \\ 12 & 13 & 11 \end{bmatrix}$$

You may take input and output through any of the default I/O methods. You do not have to specify which matrix is \$B\$ or \$C\$, as long as you output both. You may assume \$A\$ only contains positive integers. You must support matrices up to at least size \$64 \times 64\$.

### Example

```
===== Input =====
A =
 35     1     6    26    19    24
  3    32     7    21    23    25
 31     9     2    22    27    20
  8    28    33    17    10    15
 30     5    34    12    14    16
  4    36    29    13    18    11
u=
  3 5 6 1 4 2

==== Output =====
B = 
  2    27    20    31    22     9
 34    14    16    30    12     5
 29    18    11     4    13    36
  6    19    24    35    26     1
 33    10    15     8    17    28
  7    23    25     3    21    32
C = 
 17    15     8    10    28    33
 13    11     4    18    36    29
 26    24    35    19     1     6
 12    16    30    14     5    34
 21    25     3    23    32     7
 22    20    31    27     9     2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Smallest put pixel function

Task: write in any language which can generate images e.g. JavaScript, the smallest "put pixel" function. You can initialise screen inside that function or in separate code. The put-pixel function should consume 6 arguments: `x,y,r,g,b,a` where `x,y` pixel coordinates and `r,g,b,a` are color values (`a` is for alpha - transparency - you need blend new color with old color). Provide also example which use that function a draw something.

Comment: I think the way this is worded will likely make it too broad or unclear. I think it would work better if you essentially required that this function be implemented to solve a more normal golf task that you could have test cases for. For example, "given vectors `x,y,r,g,b,a` produce an image where each pixel `xi,yi` has colour `(ri,gi,bi,ai)` and the rest are black". That would usually make submissions do as you say, but avoid ambiguities like "function" and "arguments" which may not exist precisely in languages people want to use.

Answer (score 0):

## Shuffling Sequence

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Consider an operation \$f_n\$ that takes a length-\$2n\$ list and performs a perfect shuffle on it, reversing the second half. For example, \$f_4 [abcdABCD] = [aDbCcBdA]\$.

Under composition, \$f_n\$ generates a cyclic group. That is, there exists some minimal positive integer \$m\$ such that \$(f_n)^m\$ (which means \$f_n\$ composed \$m\$ times with itself) is an identical map, leaving its argument alone. Here's an example for ya:

$$f_2 [abAB] = [aBbA]$$
$$f_2 [aBbA] = [aABb]$$
$$f_2 [aABb] = [abAB]$$

$$f_2(f_2(f_2 [abAB])) = (f_2)^3 [abAB] = [abAB]$$

Since \$(f_2)^3\$ is the identity, we say that \$f_2\$ has order 3.

Your task is to determine the order of \$f_n\$. You've got a few choices for how to do this:

- Take as input \$n\$ and provide as output the order of \$f_n\$
- Take as input \$n\$ and provide as output the order of each \$f_k\$ for \$k < n\$ or for \$k \le n\$ (your choice)
- Output these orders indefinitely, beginning with that of \$f_0\$ or \$f_1\$ (your choice)

For reference, the first 77 terms (beginning from \$n = 1\$; you may optionally return \$1\$ for \$n = 0\$) are provided below. This is [OEIS A294673](https://oeis.org/A294673).

```
1,3,5,4,9,11,9,5,12,12,7,23,8,20,29,6,33,35,20,39,41,28,12,36,15,51,53,36,44,24,20,7,65,36,69,60,42,15,20,52,81,83,9,60,89,60,40,95,12,99,84,66,105,28,18,37,113,30,92,119,81,36,25,8,36,131,22,135,20,30,47,60,48,116,132,100,51,155
```

Standard [IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884) and [loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) rules apply. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program (in bytes) in each language wins! Happy golfing!

Comment: You may want to add a brief explanation that the exponentiation you use is on the group (i.e. repeated application of \$ f_{n} \$) and not the one most people are used to. I'd guess the average reader of this site doesn't know what a group is, but I may be being overcautious since it wouldn't really make much sense otherwise. Maybe run it by some people who don't know what groups are, if you can.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How's that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, but maybe I rambled too much to be clear? Anyway, my point was that I think the challenge is good but it might come off as inaccessible to users with less maths background. I suggested asking other people (maybe someone you know or people in chat) about if the wording is confusing to them.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman My mistake. What I meant was "Updated. What do you think now?" Dang ambiguity.

Comment: Haha, I didn't see the edit because I didn't scroll up, my bad. That definitely looks better, though I'm not exactly the target of my own comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Golf Golf!

This is my first challenge, so please be gentle! The challenge is to write a program that will output the correct score for a layout in the card game "Golf."

The card game Golf has many variations. The house rules I use follow the [standard rules for Six-Card Golf](https://www.pagat.com/draw/golf.html#six) given by Pagat, with one slight difference.

Each player has a 2x3 layout of cards. By the end of each round all cards are turned face up and scored as follows:

- Each ace counts 1 point.
- Each two counts minus two points.
- Each numeral card from 3 to 10 scores face value.
- Each Jack or Queen scores 10 points.
- Each King scores zero points.
- A pair of equal cards in the same column scores zero points for the column (even if the equal cards are twos).
- Three equal cards in the same row scores zero points for the row (even if the equal cards are twos).

### Input

The input can be a string or array of any kind.

### Output

An integer representing the score of the Golf hand.

### Examples

These use the notation `A23456789TJQK`.

```
Layout
AK3
J23

Score
7
-----------------------    
Layout
25Q
25J

Score
20
-----------------------        
Layout
T82
T8A

Score
-1
-----------------------        
Layout
QQQ
234

Score
5
-----------------------        
Layout
TJQ
QTJ

Score
60
```

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: I'd recommend allowing submissions to take the layout as a list of numbers with a reasonably convention. The point of this challenge appears to be in analysing the layout and applying the rules, not in performing string parsing. Otherwise this looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

## No, you don't need deep learning: AlphaGo edition

To counter the industry fad of tackling the most trivial problems with deep learning, I propose that a proof of concept be created to demonstrate that simple database queries are in fact often sufficient. To wit, I propose to demonstrate that a database query can in fact be used to do what AlphaGo does and even do it better.

The proof of concept will consist of two parts:

- A Script to create a script to create a (...) query that, given the state of a game of [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), will retrieve a move that will result in eventual victory.
- A Script to create a script to create a (...) script to initialize the database.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge so the least total bytes wins. Some rules for the challenge:

1. You may use whatever database lets you golf best
2. There is no limit for how many recursions of running the script generated by the script are required

   1. This includes directly submitting the query and (if the universe's hard drive capacity somehow permits) the init data
3. The final init script may also be an executable-ish that connects to the database backend to populate it
4. You may either pass the game state as an argument to the query or store the state in the database (storing the state in the DB doesn't count toward your score)
5. Handicap games don't need to be accounted for.

The rules of Go are, paraphrased:

- The game is played by placing black and white stones on a 19x19 grid
- The aim of the game is to score points by surrounding open space with your stones (The edges of the board count as surrounding)
- Black plays first
- A stone is part of a group if it is orthogonally connected to a member of the group
- The empty spaces orthogonally adjacent to a group are called liberties
- A group without liberties is considered captured and is removed from the board and added to the capturing player's score
- A group that can not escape capture is considered dead, and remains on the board but will count as captured for scoring purposes
- Suiciding your own group by filling its last liberty is not allowed
- Ko rule: If a single stone is captured so that capturing the capturing stone will return the board to the immediately previous state, such second capture is illegal on the turn after the first capture.
- The game ends when both players pass, indicating that they can't improve their score by playing another stone.

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: As it stands there doesn't seem to be any requirements on making actually good moves. I'm not convinced you can fix that well without making this into a [tag:king-of-the-hill] which will be a lot more work for you. Further, I suspect databases that make any actually good moves will need to be so large that you may struggle to see meaningful results.

Comment: So it looks like you want us to write a solver for go that's optimal but likely extremely slow? I suspect this will come down to implementing the rules of Go then writing a simple recursive evaluation function, and that the Go rules will take most of the work. I'm confused where the database and scripts come in.

Comment: @xnor I thought this up when I read a rather ranty blog post (which I can't seem to find anymore) about how one doesn't need deep learning, with the sole supporting argument being that data retrieval can be done with database queries.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman This is a bit of a joke challenge (see above comment for details)

Comment: Come to think of it, I could probably leave out generating the query and leave it at just the database initialization.

Answer (score 0):

**Title - Fix the note**

Given a musical note letter (`A` to `G`), followed by any number of accidentals (either 0..n `#` or 0..n `b`, not a combination of both); output a representation of the same note with the least possible number of accidentals.

A `#` means "shift the note one semitone up", and a `b` means "shift the note one semitone down".

All valid output notes are as follows (in order, then loops):

`A` `A#/Bb` `B` `C` `C#/Db` `D` `D#/Eb` `E` `F` `F#/Gb` `G` `G#/Ab`

So a sharp would move to the right along that list (and loop); and a flat would move you to the left.

**Examples**

- `A` -> `A`
- `B#` -> `C`
- `Fb` -> `E`
- `A#####` -> `D`
- `Dbbb` -> `B`
- `Gbbbbbbbbbbbb` -> G
- `Bb` -> `Bb`
- `F#` -> `F#`
- `E##` -> `F#`
- `E#` -> `F`

You can assume that the length of the input won't overflow your language.

Where the input has sharps, the output can also only contain 0..1 sharps; and vice-versa for flats.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest bytes wins. Standard rules apply

Comment: These accidentals aren't even correct. There's no such thing as E sharp sharp.

Comment: Also, should E sharp be simplified to F? Is this bass, treble, or tenor?

Comment: @JL2210 sure there is - any note can be represented as accidentals of another note, in theory. I know that in practise you wouldn't do so.

Comment: E# should be simplified to F, yes, because the aim is to reduce the number of accidentals where possible

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is this bass, treble or tenor?" - The instrument shouldn't matter for the purposes of this - this is purely theoretical (they're notes, not chords, if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

**Title: Score my Tarok hand**

Inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193547/what-is-the-score-of-my-scopa-hand)

In Slovenia (and elsewhere in central Europe), the card game Tarok is very popular. See [here](https://www.pagat.com/tarot/sltarok.html) for a complete list of rules, but essentially it is a trick taking game, played in teams that change per round.

This challenge is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, concerning the scoring of a hand, at the end of a round.

In a normal round, the game is played in partnerships. Any one player could decide the "contract" for the round, and that player (plus anyone on their team) either wins or loses the round, giving them a positive or negative score. They are known as the "Declaring team". The "Opposing team" cannot score in that round.

The input for this challenge will therefore be the Declaring team's cards, plus the contract type they bid for.

**The cards**

In a game of Tarok, there are 54 cards; as follows (shown as highest to lowest in each suit - names in brackets after a card are local names given to certain cards):

- Spades, Clubs: King, Queen, Knight, Jack, 10, 9, 8, 7
- Diamonds, Hearts: King, Queen, Knight, Jack 1, 2, 3, 4
- Taroks: Joker (škis), XXI (mond), XX, XIX, ... III, II, I (pagat)

The point value of the cards are as follows:

- kings, škis, XXI and I - 5 points each
- queens - 4 points each
- knights - 3 points each
- jacks - 2 points each
- all other cards - 1 points each

**Scoring a hand**

This is what I believe makes this challenge interesting.

- For each set of three cards in your hand, add up their values and subtract 2.
- If you end up with one or two cards left over after making the sets of three, add up their values and subtract 1.

  - So, a pair or a set of three one-point cards are both worth 1 point; but a single one-point card is worth nothing.

The total value of the pack comes to 70 card points.

In most contracts (see below), the declarer's side wins if at the end of the play they have at least 36 of the available 70 points; otherwise they lose. Because of this, the members of each team pool their cards for scoring; and so if you know the score of one team, you can calculate the score of the other.

Once the hand value has been calculated, the difference from 35 is taken (i.e. `handValue - 35`), and this difference is rounded to the nearest 5 points.

**Contracts and Bonuses**

Once the hand score is known for the declaring team, the final score is calculated based on the "contract" that was chosen at the start of the round (where "difference" is the rounded hand difference from 35, calculated above. Note this may be negative, if the opposing team got more points):

```
Contract Name          | Scoring (+ if contract won, - if lost)
------------------------------------------------
Three                  | difference +/- 10
Two                    | difference +/- 20
One                    | difference +/- 30
Solo Three             | difference +/- 40
Solo Two               | difference +/- 50
Solo One               | difference +/- 60
Beggar*                | 70 (fixed)
Solo without           | 80 (fixed)
Open Beggar*           | 90 (fixed)
Colour Valat Without** | 125 (fixed), no bonuses
Valat Without**        | 500 (fixed), no bonuses
```

With the exception of those marked, all contracts are "won" if the difference is 36 or higher; otherwise it was "lost".

`*` - to win the points, you must win no tricks (and therefore no cards)

`**` - to win the points, you must win ALL the tricks (and therefore all the cards). In this case, no other scoring bonuses are applied.

Bonus points are awarded to the declaring team, or subtracted from the declaring team if the opposing team complete the criteria. *Bonuses are only awarded on contracts where the difference is taken into account.* (i.e. from "Three" to "Solo One" only, in the above table)

```
Bonus Criteria                                | Bonus Points
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Take škis, XXI and I ("the Trule") in tricks  | 10
Take all 4 kings in tricks                    | 10
Take all the tricks ("Valat")                 | 500, no other scoring is applied
```

(note that in Tarok, there are some actions that take place during play which give additional bonuses, such as announcing at the start of the game your intention to get a certain bonus; but as those would require more inputs to calculate, I will leave these out of this challenge.)

**Some Examples**

`All 54 cards, any contract` -> +500 points

`No Cards, called Beggar` -> + 70 points

`king, king, king, king, škis, XXI, I, queen, queen, queen, queen, knight, knight, knight, knight, jack, jack, 1H, 2H; called "One"` -> 30 points for contract + 20 points difference (hand score is 56 which is 21 different from 35, so round to 20) + 10 points kings bonus + 10 points Trule Bonus = 70 points

`No cards, called "Solo One"` -> -500 (opposing team got Valat bonus)

`KS,8S,7S, called "Two"` ->failed contract, so -30 (difference), -20 (contract), -10 (opponents got Trule bonus) = -60 points

`KH, KD, škis, I, queen, queen, queen, queen, knight, knight, knight, knight, jack, jack, 1H, 2H, 7C,1D,2D,4D; called "Solo Without"` = +80 points

`KH, KD, škis, I, queen, queen, queen, queen, knight, knight, knight, knight, jack, jack, 1H, X, III,II,2D,KS; called "Three"` = +15 difference (49-35, rounded) + 10 contract = +25

Answer (score 0):

## Spreadsheet Columns

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphabet)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

In most spreadsheet programs, columns go `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `X`, `Y`, `Z`. After this comes `AA`, `AB`, `AC` ... `AX`, `AY`, `AZ`, `BA` and so on.

Your task is to convert one of these strings in to a column *number*. You must support inputs up to the maximum length of your language, to a minimum of 3.

### Test Cases:

```
A   => 1
B   => 2
Z   => 26
AA  => 27
AC  => 29
AZ  => 52
BA  => 53
FC  => 159
ID  => 238
AAA => 703
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Sandbox:

1. Are my test cases correct? They were done of the top of my head, so they may not be accurate.
2. Is this a duplicate? My searching suggests otherwise, but it may not be comprehensive.
3. Are there any other tags I could add?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your test cases are correct. I would specify how long the input can be (e.g. max of two characters) and provide some slightly larger test cases. Also, maybe the arithmetic/math tag?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Edited.

Comment: I feel as though this may be a dupe of one of the various base-conversion questions. Do you expect there is a better way to solve this than converting the letters to numbers and then interpreting them as a base 26 number? (Even if that is the best approach it won't necessarily mean it is a duplicate, I haven't checked through them yet, but I wanted to make sure you had considered it)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I had considered it. In fact, I was going to make some test cases that way, but I realised that a) I would have to convert by subtracting 10 and b) that conversion would most likely be too costly. I mean, how would you actually do that? Interpret as base 36, subtract ten, convert to string, interpret as base 26, convert to base 10? Doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: I didn't mean using builtins for base conversion, though they may be problematic too, but just [literally doing base conversion](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQqwxBMEou@tAiaOE92pgpCTmGn0WnN5eP9375DjRXCzsc9VH@vBSkLRWPIV6oWb8ufFo5x8cQJiacGJkNEdygwREYKt5ElU07Vt/oKKPFTkrZNf8).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Congratulations, you have the first answer! While good, I'm certain 63 bytes can be improved, and would be about standard for a Python answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't explained myself well. I was trying to show that base conversion questions might be a duplicate target for this one since this challenge can be solved directly with a base conversion after a very minor transformation. I haven't actually found a question that seems like a good enough target yet, but I wanted you to be aware of it (and perhaps look yourself :) ).

Comment: I think I found [a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139221/20260), though it has some annoying extra bits of copying over the row number.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174336/76162)

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a new OEIS sequence.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. The goal of this challenge is to create an integer sequence that is not in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org) using the fewest possible number of bytes.

Your program can either output an infinite list, or it can be a function from the natural numbers to the integers, which when evaluated on `1, 2, 3, 4,...` gives a sequence that is not in the OEIS.

#### Restrictions

Without any restrictions, this is a very easy challenge, we can simply write a program that prints out the constant sequence consisting of `33`, [for example](https://oeis.org/search?q=33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33%2C33).

In order to avoid accepting "easy" sequences like this, your proposed sequence cannot be a finite [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) or [entrywise product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of existing sequences or any rows or columns of [existing tables](https://oeis.org/search?q=antidiagonal%20keyword%3atabl&sort=created) in the OEIS.<sup>1</sup>

Also, I want to avoid submissions that take an otherwise disallowed sequence and prepend some list (e.g. `3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1`). Thus the above rule must stand even after ignoring the first `N` terms of the sequence.<sup>2</sup>

### Challenge

Post your source code, the first few terms of the sequence, and an explanation of what your source code is doing.

It's okay if your submission is not very mathematically interesting, but I'm hoping that one or two will be.

(Lastly, if your sequence is disqualified by someone writing is as linear combinations of existing sequences, feel free to modify/fix it, but please don't delete it.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This rule disallows all polynomials in `n`, for example, since these can be written as finite linear combinations of columns in [A009999 read as a square array](https://oeis.org/A009999/table).

<sup>2</sup> This rule also disallows all [finite-length sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=keyword%3Afini).

## Meta

*Note: I don't know if this challenge is totally silly, or if it has obvious loopholes, or if closing loopholes results in a challenge that is too difficult or arbitrary.*

- Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)
- Is this a duplicate?
- Any other restrictions? Any loosening of current restrictions?

Comment: I like the idea, but checking if an answer is valid seems really hard. For example, take n mod 13. It's not in OEIS (single-digit moduli are). But, there may well be 13 period-13 sequences in OEIS that are linearly independent, which would disqualify it. Maybe this could be a cops-and-robber style challenge where robbers try to invalidate answers, but the robber's task doesn't seem than fun.

Comment: What's to stop people from using the output of a seeded PRNG? It would be trivial to find a sequence from a seeded PRNG that doesn't exist on OEIS. The restriction of no linear combinations or entrywise products makes it more difficult to validate, but it is almost certainly still possible.

Comment: @Mego, exactly the sort of feedback I was hoping for. I don't know how to elegantly work around that sort of answer—especially since a PRNG from a library wouldn't be in the spirit of the question, but a PRNG written by the user would be a great answer. I think I'll avoid submitting this question.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, ideas like linear combinations etc. start to break down when the sequences end.  All (or at least most) OEIS sequences only have a finite number of terms present, some only even have a finite number of terms that can be calculated with modern computing power.  So how do we deal with the finiteness of the sequences?

Comment: I don't know whether the issues raised in earlier comments can be fixed, but if they can then there's another which can and should be: OEIS isn't static. If someone comes up with an interesting answer, it may well be submitted to OEIS. There are various ways to solve this problem: the easiest to verify would be to say that OEIS sequences beyond Axxxxxx can be ignored, where the sequence chosen is e.g. the highest numbered one with no assigned but unpublished gaps below it.

Answer (score 0):

## Draw a CE mark [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

Your input is the scaling factor `n`. You must output an image of width `82n` and height `48n` (if you are generating a vector image, it should have that as its default size). The image will be either transparent or white, with the following regions in black:

- The segment of a ring centred at `24n,24n` of outer radius `20n` and inner radius `14n` that is left of the vertical line at `26n`.
- A copy of that segment displaced `34n` to the right. The original rings would therefore exactly overlap if they were not segments.
- A rectangle with upper left corner at `44n,21n` and lower right corner at `56n,27n`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is different enough from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26689/194

Answer (score 0):

## Typhoon: Where am I from? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[classification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)

#### Introduction

A typhoon is basically a hurricane in the northwestern Pacific region. Unlike hurricanes, typhoons are named by 14 regions, each providing 10 names, adding up to 140 names. The 140 names are used in a cyclic pattern; after the last name is used, the first one will be used again. The names may sometimes be retired, mainly because of the devastation the typhoon with those names have made.

Here are the 140 names.

[image]

```
[Text-only]

Region             Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4   Column 5   Column 6   Column 7   Column 8   Column 9   Column 10
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cambodia           Damrey     Ampil      Kong-rey   Krosa      Nakri      Maysak     Krovanh    Chanthu    Trases     Nesat
China              Haikui     Wukong     Yutu       Bailu      Fengshen   Haishen    Dujuan     Dianmu     Mulan      Haitang
DPR Korea          Kirogi     Jongdari   Toraji     Podul      Kalmaegi   Noul       Surigae    Mindulle   Meari      Nalgae
Hong Kong, China   Yun-yeung  Shanshan   Man-yi     Lingling   Fung-wong  Dolphin    Choi-wan   Lionrock   Ma-on      Banyan
Japan              Koinu      Yagi       Usagi      Kajiki     Kammuri    Kujira     Koguma     Kompasu    Tokage     Yamaneko
Lao PDR            Bolaven    Leepi      Pabuk      Faxai      Phanfone   Chan-hom   Champi     Namtheun   Hinnamnor  Pakhar
Macao, China       Sanba      Bebinca    Wutip      Peipah     Vongfong   Linfa      In-fa      Malou      Muifa      Sanvu
Malaysia           Jelawat    Rumbia     Sepat      Tapah      Nuri       Nangka     Cempaka    Nyatoh     Merbok     Mawar
Micronesia         Ewiniar    Soulik     Mun        Mitag      Sinlaku    Saudel     Nepartak   Rai        Nanmadol   Guchol
Philippines        Maliksi    Cimaron    Danas      Hagibis    Hagupit    Molave     Lupit      Malakas    Talas      Talim
RO Korea           Gaemi      Jebi       Nari       Neoguri    Jangmi     Goni       Mirinae    Megi       Noru       Doksuri
Thailand           Prapiroon  Mangkhut   Wipha      Bualoi     Mekkhala   Atsani     Nida       Chaba      Kulap      Khanun
U.S.A.             Maria      Barijat    Francisco  Matmo      Higos      Etau       Omais      Aere       Roke       Lan
Viet Nam           Son-Tinh   Trami      Lekima     Halong     Bavi       Vamco      Conson     Songda     Sonca      Saola

[JSON]

{"Cambodia":["Damrey","Ampil","Kong-rey","Krosa","Nakri","Maysak","Krovanh","Chanthu","Trases","Nesat"],"China":["Haikui","Wukong","Yutu","Bailu","Fengshen","Haishen","Dujuan","Dianmu","Mulan","Haitang"],"DPR Korea":["Kirogi","Jongdari","Toraji","Podul","Kalmaegi","Noul","Surigae","Mindulle","Meari","Nalgae"],"Hong Kong, China":["Yun-yeung","Shanshan","Man-yi","Lingling","Fung-wong","Dolphin","Choi-wan","Lionrock","Ma-on","Banyan"],"Japan":["Koinu","Yagi","Usagi","Kajiki","Kammuri","Kujira","Koguma","Kompasu","Tokage","Yamaneko"],"Lao PDR":["Bolaven","Leepi","Pabuk","Faxai","Phanfone","Chan-hom","Champi","Namtheun","Hinnamnor","Pakhar"],"Macao, China":["Sanba","Bebinca","Wutip","Peipah","Vongfong","Linfa","In-fa","Malou","Muifa","Sanvu"],"Malaysia":["Jelawat","Rumbia","Sepat","Tapah","Nuri","Nangka","Cempaka","Nyatoh","Merbok","Mawar"],"Micronesia":["Ewiniar","Soulik","Mun","Mitag","Sinlaku","Saudel","Nepartak","Rai","Nanmadol","Guchol"],"Philippines":["Maliksi","Cimaron","Danas","Hagibis","Hagupit","Molave","Lupit","Malakas","Talas","Talim"],"RO Korea":["Gaemi","Jebi","Nari","Neoguri","Jangmi","Goni","Mirinae","Megi","Noru","Doksuri"],"Thailand":["Prapiroon","Mangkhut","Wipha","Bualoi","Mekkhala","Atsani","Nida","Chaba","Kulap","Khanun"],"U.S.A.":["Maria","Barijat","Francisco","Matmo","Higos","Etau","Omais","Aere","Roke","Lan"],"Viet Nam":["Son-Tinh","Trami","Lekima","Halong","Bavi","Vamco","Conson","Songda","Sonca","Saola"]}
```

This chart is based from that on the [Japan Meteorological Agency website](http://www.jma.go.jp/jma/jma-eng/jma-center/rsmc-hp-pub-eg/tyname.html), retrieved on 10 October 2019. Conventionally the list is divided into 5 columns, but in order to list all the names by region, I have organized them into 10 columns, so that each row fits all names from the same region. Moreover, two of the names, Mangkhut and Rumbia are retired and are still pending for replacement. Here I will keep these 2 names for integrity.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function, that receives a name in the list above as input, and returns or outputs which region it is named after.

The input and output formats are flexible. For input, you may omit the hyphens and/or receive all uppercase or lowercase input. For output, you may also instead return an element from a set of 14 distinct values of your choice, each representing a region.

Your program does not need to deal with invalid inputs.

#### Sample I/O

```
Input: Chan-hom (exact wording)
Output: Lao PDR (exact wording)

Input: Kongrey (Kon-grey; without hyphen)
Output: KH (Cambodia; ISO 3166 code, uppercase)

Input: atsani (Atsani; all lowercase)
Output: th (Thailand; ISO 3166 code, lowercase)

Input: LAN (Lan; all uppercase)
Output: 12 (U.S.A; 0-indexed)

Input: choiwan (Choi-wan; without hyphen & all lowercase)
Output: 4 (Hong Kong, China; 1-indexed)

Input: INFA (In-fa; without hyphen & all uppercase)
Output: Macau (Macao, China; common name)
```

Again, you may have different output formats, but the input and output formats you use must be stated.

#### Winning Criteria

The shortest submission in each language wins. No loophole is allowed.

Comment: Please add a table in a machine readable format.

Comment: @Adám Added just below the image.

Comment: How about CSV or JSON?

Comment: @Adám I think I will add a json version.

Comment: @Adám Added the corresponding JSON for the table.

Comment: Unfortunately, this challenge becomes more about compressing the table than anything else :-(

Comment: @Adám I know that's just some reverse lookup, but well my intent is to see how this can be golfed smartly actually hmm..

Comment: Without compression, the best I came up with was to take input without dashes, but with capitals, then remove "rona" and look it up in a string of first-three-letters-except-"rona". You *could* give the table as an input…

Answer (score 0):

How often does the word sixty-eight (68) appear in numbers from 1 to N. The upper limit for N to which the program needs to be able to perform is 100 000 000.

The program will take N as input and return every number in which the word sixty-eight appears from 1 to N, and a sum of all appearances of sixty-eight at the end.

I'm looking for the spoken form, so the word sixty-eight appears in

68 000 000 - *sixty-eight* million - **once**

68 680 000 - *sixty-eight* million six-hundred thousand - **once**

68 068 068 - *sixty-eight* million *sixty-eight* thousand and *sixty-eight* - **three times**

and so on. The shortest implementation that gives a correct result wins.

Comment: Thank you so much for using the sandbox.

Comment: Alright, no tie-breaker then

Comment: What, exactly, is a "sum of all appearances of sixty-eight at the end"? Also, there is a typo in your second test case I think (should be six-hundred eighty thousand, right?).

Comment: 68 680 000 should be sixty-eight million six-hundred **eighty** thousand, right?

Answer (score 0):

### Intersect the integer ranges

Integer ranges take one of four forms:

1. A start, a step and an end. Both ends are included in the range. The difference between the end and start is guaranteed to be a multiple of the step. The step is guaranteed to be positive, even if the start is equal to the end (it may not be greater).
2. A start and a step. This is a half-infinite range.
3. A step and an end. This is also a half-infinite range.
4. An empty range. You can decide how you want to represent this, but you must accept as input any empty range you can output.

Given two integer ranges, please output their intersection.

1. If the two ranges are disjoint, return an empty range.
2. If the two ranges are identical, simply output one of them.
3. If one range completely subsumes the other, output the latter.
4. Determine the values common to both ranges, and output a range that represents these values.

Examples:

```
[1, 1, 6] ∩ [3, 1, 9] = [3, 1, 6]
[1, 2, 9] ∩ [2, 1, 8] = [2, 2, 8]
[1, 2, ~] ∩ [2, 3, ~] = [5, 6, ~]
[~, 2, 9] ∩ [1, 3, ~] = [1, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3] ∩ [2, 2, 2] = []
```

If would be nice if you could indicate any preconditions that your answer doesn't require (e.g. if it works for a step of zero when the start and end are the same).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: `[] v []` makes it look like you want the union (`∪`) instead of intersection (`∩`)

Comment: @Kroppeb Whoops, I was so lazy that not only didn't I look up the right character but I used the wrong ASCII character too... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

## Doing something with Haifu

[Haifu](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/haifu.html) is an esoteric programming language by David Morgan-Mar, which, in addition to having a very weird control scheme also has the requirement that each program should be in the form of Haiku.

Maybe it would be possible to do a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)-like challenge with it. The robber's task is to write a Haifu program doing *something* non-trivial, using a shorthand code, where each command/variable is replaced by a unique single- or two-character identifier, and ignoring the haiku structure demand (The language is weird enough that even "Hello World" isn't a trivial task). The cop's task is to take a robber's code and turn it into a valid Haiku. However, this would either be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), or maybe even outsourced to a different SE site.

### Meta questions:

Is this a feasible concept and does it fit into the spirit of CodeGolf.SE?

The Haifu specification is not quite complete. If I'd be doing this, I'd need first some sharp eyes to help me spot all the holes and fill them. Then, the shortened syntax for the coding part would need to be designed. If enough people say it might be feasible, I'll probably open a chat room to discuss this.

Lastly, of course, what to do with the turning code into Haiku part of the challenge?

Comment: Is there an implementation of Haifu already? Regardless, based on the allowance of comments in the poems it does not appear difficult to produce any particular program in Haifu (though golfing is a different matter). Making this a popularity contest sounds like a rather bad idea - what objective voting criterion would you be considering? Of course, if you make one yourself you could probably post it to puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

## Title: Station Codes

#### Background

In the UK, railway stations are assigned three-letter ["CRS" codes](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/48541.aspx) (e.g. "Chester" = `CTR`, "Caterham" = `CAT`). Something similar is also used for airports worldwide (IATA codes).

#### Challenge

The challenge is to take in the three letter code as the input, and present the name of the station as the output.

The codes are always in upper-case; the outputs are as shown in the link above.

Usual IO rules, exclusions; code-golf rules apply.

#### Examples

- `CAT` -> `Caterham`
- `CCH` -> `Chichester`
- `HHY` -> `Highbury & Islington`
- `HOP` -> `Hope (Derbyshire)`
- `AUW` -> `Ascott-under-Wychwood`
- `CSD` -> `Cobham & Stoke d'Abernon`
- `HID` -> `Hall-i'-th'-Wood`
- `HXX` -> `Heathrow Airport Terminals 1, 2 and 3`
- `ELY` -> `Ely`
- anything else listed in the link above - the correct station name
- anything not listed in the link above -> no preference

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Sandbox Query

Is this boring? - does it add anything to the existing gamut of "compress a load of data and index it" -type questions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this challenge is going to be interesting or not, as there are so many codes and I'm not sure if most of them can be formulated. But anyways I think you need to list all of the codes in your question as the link can go down or change. Generally challenges should be self containing without the need to open any external links or resources.

Comment: Is their any logic to the limited subset of stations you've chosen for the challenge? This isn't, strictly, KC, by the way.

Comment: @Night2 Thanks, I'll list out the codes.

Comment: @Shaggy the codes I used in the examples were chosen because they cover the all the non-alpha characters in the station names. The challenge, though. uses the entire set of CRS codes, as published by Network Rail. Are there some other codes you're thinking of that aren't covered by that list (now included in the question also)?

Comment: @Night2 actually I can't include the codes, it's too many characters so it exceeds the limit of 30,000 characters

Comment: That is a problem for itself, about 40k characters for a code golf challenge. Even if there was a formula to 100% of the times, match an input code to a station name, there would still be around 30k characters for station names to store.

Answer (score 0):

## Can I run this?

I'm a big fan of [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges, and an idea recently struck me. Suppose you're on a *nix system and you want to know how many executable programs you have installed that you can run. Given a file with mode `mode`, you can run it if it is a normal file (`mode & S_IFMT == S_IFREG`) **and** any of the following are true:

- Its owner is equal to your effective user id and `0100 & p != 0` (user executable bit is set)
- Its group is a group you are a member of and `0010 & p != 0` (group executable bit is set)
- `0001 & p != 0` (world executable bit is set)

#### Rules:

> TODO: See below.

---

> ### For Sandbox
>
> Writing a good [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) challenge is hard.
>   I have some ideas, but I've brainstormed some easy solutions and I want to know which challenge and restrictions would be most well-received.
>
> There are three possible challenges I am considering:
>
> - **single file**: Given a path as input, output truthy/falsy whether the path is a path to a file the user can run.
> - **count in directory**: output the number of files the user can run at any depth underneath the current working directory (or a provided directory, should you prefer that)
> - **count in `PATH`**: output the number of files the user can run immediately under any directory in the environment variable `PATH`. The value of `PATH` may also be given as input to the program/function.
>
> Potential restrictions (I marked as spoilers since these can provide solutions if I don't ban them):
>
> - > Banning the use of `access()`/`os.access()`/etc.
> - > Banning the use of the `which` executable typically found on *nix machines (`which` is exactly the solution to the first challenge)
> - > Banning the use of any external executables
>
> I am currently inclined to choose the second challenge, allow all solutions, but award a bounty to the shortest program which follows the above restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement Or [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

**or** is a dubious esoteric programming language. The author is unknown but it is known that fungot (a chatbot) is currently learning **or** but it remains unknown how it does it and where it receives the required material to learn **or**. Check out [this](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Or#IRC_Log) IRC log to see fungot revealing part of the language.

## Instruction reference

It is only known that a space followed by an f pushes *false* to the stack. The *false* value may by any falsy value of your choosing. Since this language does not support output, in order to make verifying answers possible, you should output the resulting stack in the end of the program.

## Test cases

Expects one false to the stack

```
 f
```

Expects 2 falses on the stack

```
m f ma f
```

Expects 1 false on the stack

```
 f a lf
```

Expects 2 falses on the stack

```
a f fa
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- I haven't found a duplicate, but anything?
- Tags are code-golf, string and interpreter. Anything else?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string).

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string).

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string).

Answer (score 0):

## Make a karaoke machine

Given a list of lines and a set time (in seconds) which those lines appear, output those lines after that specific amount of seconds.

### Example input:

```
0 Hello there!
5 This line should come up after 5 seconds.
10 This line should come up 5 seconds after that one.
20 There's a 10-second delay here.
```

Every line will be preceded by an integer, separated from the rest of the line by a string. The number indicates when the line should come up - the first line should be outputted instantly, followed by the next few lines like so:

```
Hello there! (output instantly)
(wait 5 seconds)
This line should come up after 5 seconds.
(wait 5 seconds)
This line should come up 5 seconds after that one.
(wait 10 seconds)
There's a 10-second delay here.
```

### Assumptions:

- You're guaranteed that the lines are in order - i.e. this doesn't happen:

  ```
  5 Hello there!
  0 Oops, this is meant to happen before the first line.
  ```
- You're also guaranteed that no two lines share the same time.

### Winning criteria:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: No problem in particular. However I'd expect that many solution will have unbounded drift when the number of lines increases, so you may ban that (w. r. t. the system clock if there's one, for example) plus, I suppose that lines are short enough such that printing them takes a negligible time.

Comment: I found several related challenges: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119636/31625) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104372/31625) [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60188/31625). None of them were quite the same, but I think they all suffered from some of the problems that user202729 mentioned. Most of them still went well, but I think being more rigorous won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

## Interpolate between binary images

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)

While there are various ways to interpolate between images with a large color space where for each color there are many similar other colors, it is not so straightforward to do that in a (heavily) quantized color space where you only have few colors available. We now take that to an extreme:

Given two black and white image of the same size as well as a number \$N\$, output a sequence of \$N\$ images that "interpolate" between the two input pictures.

The goal here is coming up with an "interpolation" algorithm that allows you to smoothly transition between two images. But *how* you define this *smoothness* is up to you. The more aesthetically pleasing the better.

#### Details

- "black and white" here means the images consist only of the colors black and white, no grays.
- Validity criteria:

  - The first image in the sequence must be the first input image, and
    the last image in the sequence must be the second image.
  - All images
    must have the same size and consist of only black and white pixels.
    Furthermore the output must be deterministic in the sense that if you
    repeatedly call the program with identical inputs, you must get
    identical outputs.
- Please post the sequence of images as an animation in your answer, for any \$N\$ you choose.

#### Examples

To be defined...

Comment: popularity contests are at this point considered almost considered "historical". You need a clear scoring criterion for a valid challenge, which in your case means defining smoothness as something better than just "It's up to you"

Comment: @AlienAtSystem The popularity contests need *validity criteria*, but no scoring criteria - we discussed this quite thoroughly about 2 years ago. The problem is that you cannot force people to vote according to a specific way, but you have to design the contest in a way that the desired output is something people will like anyway. It is not really historical, it is just rare that good popularity contests are written. Check out the discussions linked [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/updating-the-popularity-contest-tag-info-suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

Draw a hexagonal grid `n×m` of ascii hexagons

```
  ____
 /    \
/      \
\      /
 \____/
```

with numbers somewhere within each of them, such as numbers goes in snail order starting in the center (but without empty hexagons):

```
  ____        ____        ____        ____        ____        ____
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/      \____/  25  \____/      \____/      \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/      \____/  26  \____/  24  \____/      \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/  27  \____/  11  \____/  23  \____/      \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/  28  \____/  12  \____/  10  \____/  22  \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/  13  \____/  3   \____/  9   \____/  40  \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/  29  \____/  4   \____/  2   \____/  21  \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/  14  \____/  1   \____/  8   \____/  39  \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/  30  \____/  5   \____/  7   \____/  20  \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/  15  \____/  6   \____/  19  \____/  38  \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/  31  \____/  16  \____/  18  \____/  37  \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/  32  \____/  17  \____/  36  \____/      \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/      \____/  33  \____/  35  \____/      \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/      \____/  34  \____/      \____/      \____/
 /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \
/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \
\      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /    \      /
 \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/      \____/
```

Comment: 1. Can you provide examples for smaller various `n,m`s? Especially, I want to see examples for odd and even widths. 2. Should the numbers be distinct in every cell? 3. Assuming the answer to 2 is true, What should we do if the number doesn't fit in a single line inside the hexagon (i.e. 7 digits or higher)?

Comment: Maybe we should assume n,m to be odd.

Answer (score 0):

**Monokeyed Words**

*(Based on https://what-if.xkcd.com/75/)*

Old mobile phones had letters and numbers assigned to the same key, as follows:

- 1
- 2abc
- 3def
- 4ghi
- 5jkl
- 6mno
- 7pqrs
- 8tuv
- 9wxyz
- 0 [space]

From any given list of words or phrases (arbitrary number of inputs, formed of 0-9 a-z and space), find the word which has the most consecutive characters on the same key, and output the key and the count (in any reasonable format)

for example:

- `[nonmonogamous],[qwerty],[false]` -> `7, 6` (seven times on the 6 key - nonmonogamous)
- `[tutu],[cat],[mouse]` -> `4, 8` (four times on the 8 key - tutu)
- `[cab],[mon],[tin],[tom]` -> `3,2` (cab) or `3,6` (mon) - either answer is valid
- `[#],[!!!],[is this valid?]` -> any output or error - doesn't fit valid inputs. `2,4` would also be acceptable, for `hi` in `is this valid?`
- `bacmon`, `habitat`, `fringe`, `be`, `test`, `valid` -> `3,2` or `3,6` as it's a tie between those keys
- `01452301146` -> `2,1` (two in a row on the 1 key)

The output format isn't fixed, so you could also output `[3][6]` or `3.6` or `6,3` - anything you like, as long as it's consistent which is the key and which the number of repetitions. You could also use one of the letters to represent the key, if you wanted - e.g. instead of `3,6` you could output `3,m`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), usual exclusions etc. apply

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "wordlists." You don't appear to want us to check a lexicon (as `9wxyz9wxyz` isn't a word in any language I know). If you just mean an input which is a list of strings then you don't need to do anything besides say that - the default rules will handle that no problem. Aside from that, this seems to have some "fluff" in that I think you'd be better off asking for just a summary (i.e. the longest chain of what button) of one input word or just finding the maximal word(s) from a list. Once you have one, getting the other is more or less trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was originally wanting to do exactly the same as the link (i.e. look up based on a whole dictionary), but I changed my mind part way through. As for the "fluff", yes OK I can see that; I'll edit my question

Comment: I think changing your mind halfway has happened to all of us at least once :) That said, I find your edits somewhat confusing - you seem to have changed it to just be one word in the new test cases but have kept the old ones.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman yes, the program should be able to take an aribtrary number of inputs

Answer (score 0):

## Description

[Cornhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornhole) is a game in which players take turns throwing bags filled with corn kernels(or other fillers) onto a wooden board with a hole in the far end. If a bag goes through the hole, it counts as 3 points. If a bag stays on top of the board without falling off it counts as 1 point.

Score is taken at the end of each round in which the two players throw 4 bags (alternating). Only the net score is calculated.

The first to **exactly** 21 points is the winner. If a player were to score points in a round that would bring them to exceed 21 points, the points for that round are subtracted from the players score.

## Rule

1. Given an array of scores from multiple rounds of Cornhole, determine the current score of the game.

## Input

The input will be an array of one or more rounds of scores for each bag throw by both players alternating. (you may choose any 3 distinct symbols to cover the scenario of misses, 1 point, or 3 points)

`[0,0,1,0,3,3,1,1,0,0,1,0,3,3,1,1]`

- In this scenario

  - Player A missed the first shot, Player B missed their first shot, Player A landed the bag on the board for their second shot, Player B missed their second shot, Player A made it in the hole for their third shot, Player B made it in the hole for their third shot, Player A landed on the board for their fourth shot, and Player B landed on their board for their fourth shot.
  - In the next round of play, Player A missed the first shot, Player B missed their first shot, Player A landed the bag on the board for their second shot, Player B missed their second shot, Player A made it in the hole for their third shot, Player B made it in the hole for their third shot, Player A landed on the board for their fourth shot, and Player B landed on their board for their fourth shot.

## Output

The score of the Cornhole match as an array of two numbers. From the input above, the output would be:

```
[2,0]
```

Examples:

```
 Insert multiple samples of scoring, including one example of a player scoring over 21 and losing points
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox reviewers, thanks for checking this out. I posted [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195881/reconstruct-a-video-where-the-frames-pixels-have-been-shuffled) question (after a few revisions) as a code challenge and pretty much no one likes it. Please give some feedback as to why it's not appropriate, clear, fun, or whatever other criticism you have. I think it's a very interesting problem and I'd love to see some other approaches to it along with some interesting language choices :).

I think the main criticism is how to measure accuracy. I've added a script to calculate a score between the competition video and whatever video contestants submit. Please tell me why that is insufficient, or unfair, unclear, etc.

Again, any feedback for improvement is welcome! I really want to see some interesting solutions :).

Thanks again for reviewing!

## TITLE: Reconstruct a video where the frames' pixels have been shuffled

Given a video where all the pixels of every frame have been scrambled with some image scrambling function T(frame), reconstruct the original. T only operates on one frame at a time and has no persistent state between invocations. It's just a constant random map that shuffles pixels to new locations each frame. T is constant and performs the same permutation each frame.

Essentially you have to recover all of the spatial information that's been removed.

Prepare to bake your noodle golfers, this is a doozy!

### Background

Since the spatial mapping needs to be determined, the scrambled video source needs to be something with significant motion. An example would be an episode of your favorite sitcom. Lots of colors, lots of movement between and around frames.

Simple example of the scrambling function T(frame):

```python
SourceImage = [44,22,33,55]

T(SourceImage) = [33,44,22,55]

T maps {0:2, 1:0, 2:1, 3:3}
```

This example has the image in a 1D array.
For the problem however, the image would be a 2D RGB image.

### Rules

- You are allowed to process the entire video to determine Ti.
- Ti does not have to be a 100% perfect inverse, which my not even be possible depending on the input.
- No loopholes. Your program should at a minimum take the example scrambled video as input ('scrambled_city.mp4' below) and output the unscrambled video that is as close to the original as possible ('city.mp4').
- After producing the output video, calculate your score with the provided average MSE python script below.
- Submit your unscrambled program source, your average MSE score and your calculated unscrambled video file, see **Submission** below.
- Providing your source code and unscrambled video lets the hivemind confirm your submission is honest.

### Scoring

The answer which most accurately reconstructs the video is the winner.
Accuracy will be calculated as the avgerage of [Mean Squared Error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) of all hidden source and corresponding reconstructed frames, nothing fancy, and should be as close to 0 as possible.

### Notes

- Unscrambling a randomly shuffled image by itself is impossible. A video is different, it's possible to some degree.
- Feel free to post any algorithms already known to accomplish this.
- This problem is very difficult so if you can generate any unscrambled images that don't look like pure garbage consider yourself a success.

### Competition Videos

Hidden source video **'city.mp4'**: [Full Hidden Source Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B-s2MmIzq6F6vBIvQTySHkdvPqm0hbZX)
Your algorithm should work without access to this!
[image: Frame 250]

Scrambled video (seed 9001) **'scrambled_city.mp4'**: [Full Scrambled Video - 2GB](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NwQF3aciZCmhlxSTBQrmP1QmsOxELWQp)
[image: Frame 250 - Scrambled]

[source webpage for other videos to use](https://mazwai.com/video/one-big-picnic/455035)

### Python code to generate test cases for you:

This will take a video (infile) and output it's scrambled version (outfile).

Dependency: opencv2+ (pip3 install opencv-python)

```python
import cv2

infile = 'city.mp4'
outfile = 'scrambled_city.avi'
seed = 9001

def scramble(image):
    copy = image.copy()
    # reset the seed each frame so we have constant transform function.
    cv2.setRNGSeed(seed) 
    cv2.randShuffle(copy)
    return copy

# Open video, read first frame
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(infile)
success,image = vidcap.read()

# Create video writer with same dimensions
h,w,layers = image.shape
size = (w,h)
outvideo = cv2.VideoWriter(outfile,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG'), 30, size, True)
print( 'videosize: %s\n'%repr(size))

count = 0
while success:
    scrambled = scramble(image)
    # DUMP SCRAMBLED JPG
    #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, scrambled)

    # VIDEO FRAME OUTPUT
    outvideo.write(scrambled)

    print( 'frame: %d   %s'%(count,str(success)) , end='\r') 
    count += 1
    success,image = vidcap.read()

outvideo.release()
vidcap.release()
```

### Python code to calculate avg Mean Square Error over two videos

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

infile1 = 'city.mp4'
infile2 = 'scrambled_city.avi'

# https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/
def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the
    # sum of the squared difference between the two images;
    # NOTE: the two images must have the same dimension
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])
    
    # return the MSE, the lower the error, the more "similar"
    # the two images are
    return err

# Open video, read first frame
vid1 = cv2.VideoCapture(infile1)
success1,image1 = vid1.read()
vid2 = cv2.VideoCapture(infile2)
success2,image2 = vid2.read()
count = 0
sumMSE = 0
while success1 and success2:
    sumMSE += mse(image1,image2)
    count += 1
    print( 'frame: %d    avgMSE=%f'%(count,sumMSE/float(count)) , end='\r') 
    success1,image1 = vid1.read()
    success2,image2 = vid2.read()

print("\n[Frames: %d] Avg MSE = %f"%(count,sumMSE/float(count)))
vid1.release()
vid2.release()
```

Example output avgMSE of city.mp4 and scrambled_city.avi:

> [Frames: 5113] avg MSE = 18079.870445918445

Example output avgMSE of city.mp4 and city.mp4:

> [Frames: 5113] avg MSE = 0.000000

### SUBMISSION + HIDDEN TEST CASES

When you're ready to submit your solution, please score your submission against the example video and for fun include unscrambled versions of the three test cases below.

First (required):

- Your solution code. No code provided is disqualification.
- Submit the avg MSE for your reconstructed 'scrambled_city.mp4' and the first example video, 'city.mp4', you calculate from the provided python script.
- Your unscrambled video file (suggestion: host on youtube or G-drive).
- You do not need to include your calculation of T or Ti, the visual media you provide (step above) will be enough to prove your algorithm works and score it.

~~ Lowest score wins. Good luck!  ~~

Second (optional for fun): You can submit your completely unscrambled videos OR you can submit the unscrambled frames 250,500,750,1000 for all 3 of the test cases below. It will be pretty clear if you solved it or not. They're very recognizable scenes.

Note: The youtube preview is terribly distorted. The downloaded files are much better quality.

[video 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=173fMIDnA5SBI3MjuxUdPYV8qvL4CqDTp)

[video 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qzrJoZ2I4lA86AlXQtohOueuf0PCFQ3o)

[video 3 - HARD](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ykYeFrKWP-VT8TsjSPOhfQWZ80XENnqq)

Comment: The issue I see is the ambiguity of the sentence "T only operates on one frame at a time and has no persistent state between invocations." If T does not perform the same permutation on all frames, the challenge is simply impossible. In addition, the test cases are all ridiculously huge. 2GB of data for a simple test case is way too much.

Comment: I don't think this one is solvable even if T *did* perform the same permutation on all frames. Its like the [Auditors](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Auditors_of_Reality) atomizing paintings to try and figure out why they're beautiful. Also holy hell that test case is literally the worst: a collection of short, unconnected, sequences that are only a few seconds long at best. How is any algorithm supposed to find any patterns in that?

Comment: T is constant. I clarified the phrasing. Ok I'll add a second smaller video. Maybe 100MB? It's difficult to get smaller because the compression algorithms don't like it when the frames are noisy. Compressing the scrambled version too much would actually make it impossible.

Comment: [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35005/45613)

Comment: @Beefster I think you have referred to a similar but different problem. In that problem there is a simple reversible algorithm and you (as in the person reading this) get to decide how to map/unmap the values. However, in this problem the only thing you are presented with is a scrambled video and the knowledge that it's scrambling function is constant. You don't know anything else. Now try your best to unscramble the video.

Comment: @extracrispy are you going for a [tag:cops-and-robbers] then?

Comment: Adding a sentence is not the same as clarifying. The misleading information is still the first thing people read. And I think before asking people to perform a task like this, you should consider how you would go about it yourself. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhot5j43z29fh7c/PerlinShuffled.webp?dl=0) is a very small (32x32x32) and easy (3d perlin noise: it's smooth in all dimensions) test case for you. Show me that you could unshuffle it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

### SandChallenges for Proposed box [draft] [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

In this challenge you should simulate how "challenges" interact with each other. (You need to output how many iterations have the "challenges" done.)

### Symbols used in the documentation

SandChallenges is played on a 3x3 grid.

- `X` represents a challenge. It challenges the grid next to its position.
- represents an empty sandpile. This is what the "challenges" move in their actions.
- `.` represents moving sandpiles and is only used in this documentation. Input will never contain those characters; it instead will only contain `X` and .

### A closer look at `X` challenges

There are sandpiles between those "challenges". When a "challenge" is active, it pushes sand towards the next grid. The next grid is described as the following:

- The next grid is usually the grid on the right.
- If the grid is on the right edge, the next grid becomes the first grid of the next line.
- If the grid is on the last line, the next grid becomes the first grid of the first line.

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

The next grid of `A` is `B`, the next grid of `C` is `D`, and the next grid of `I` is `A`.

---

Another rule: they can get buried by active sandpiles. This makes them fail to function.

### Test cases

Spaces are replaced with semicolons for readability problems.

```
X;;
;;;
;;;
```

-> (Affecting the next cell)

```
X.;
;;;
;;;
```

->

```
X..    X..    X..           X..
;;; -> .;; -> ..; -> ... -> ...
;;;    ;;;    ;;;           ...

After that the "challenge" gets buried by active sandpiles, which results in the following state:

...
...
...

This box had went through 9 changes before it stops.
```

---

```
XXX    ...
XXX -> ...
XXX    ...

This means that the challenge had went through 1 change before it stops. All of them push active sand and buries themselves simultaneously.
```

---

```
X;;    X.;
;X; -> ;X.
;;X    ;;X
```

The bottom-right challenge shoots active sand, which buries the active challenge in the same iteration:

```
..;    ...    ...    ...
;X. -> ;X. -> .X. -> ...
;;X    .;X    ..X    ...

This goes through 4 iterations.
```

---

```
X;;    X.;    X..    ...
X;; -> X.; -> X.. -> ...
X;;    X.;    X..    ...

This goes though 3 iterations.
```

---

```
X;X    X.X    ...    ...
;X; -> .X. -> ... -> ...
;X;    ;X.    .X.    ...

This goes through 3 iterations.
```

---

```
X;X    ..X    ...
;X; -> .X. -> ...
X;X    X.X    ...
This goes through 2 iterations.
```

### Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- Any amount of extraneous whitespace is permitted, provided the characters line up appropriately.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.

## Meta

- Is this clear enough? Any better wordings for sections?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Tags are [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) and [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string). Any suggestions?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: As posed the challenge appears too simple. The wrapping method of the grid means you can just save it as a 1d object and reshape it for the output alone. There is no reason why the challenge should be restricted to a 3x3 grid either. Also, you're not clearly stating what you want the output to be. And lastly, that pun for the sake of pun is horrible and will just confuse people.

Comment: I mostly agree with the other comment. This seems to be a lot of fluff for "find the longest substring of semicolons in the input." It may even wind up being a dupe because of that - I was going to suggest having them propagate both ways, but I'm pretty sure that is a duplicate as well! If you allow the grid to be any size and make the sandboxes propagate in more directions you may have a good base to build off of.

Answer (score 0):

### How long should this song last?

Enter the world of sheet music. A composition (the musical piece, which may or may not be a song) is divided into bars. The length of a bar is defined by the time signature.
The time signature states how the bar is divided into beats, and what length of note carries the beat.

Note lengths are always powers of 2. 4 means a quarter note, 2 a half note, 8 an eighth note (or a quaver if you're a snob), etcetera. A half note (2) is twice the length of a quarter note (4), which is itself twice the length of a quaver (8), and so on.

A time signature may look like this: 3/4. The 4 means that the quarter note carries the beat, and the 3 means that there are 3 of them in one bar. 3/2 means there are three half-notes in a beat, 7/8 means there are seven quavers, and so on.

Now, the actual speed at which a piece is to be performed depends on the tempo. That is usually expressed in beats per minute (bpm). The tempo also defines the note carrying the beat (usually the same as the one in the time signature but not always). So, you can have the time signature be 8=150, meaning there are 150 quavers in a minute (in the sheet music it would be notated ♪=150).

Both tempo and time signature can change throughout the composition.

#### Challenge

Use the following format for your input (or something very similar). It is a list of events:

```
[1,"4/4"],
[1,"4=120"],
[521,""]
```

This is the simplest form. It is a list of integer-string pairs (you're obviously free to go with string-string pairs if it makes your program simpler). The integer defines at which bar the event happens (starting from 1), and the string defines what happens there. If it is in the form of x/y, then it is a new time signature. If it is in the form of x=y, you have a new tempo. Lastly, an empty string designates the end of the score (exclusive, so the above example has 520 bars).

With changes, the format may look like this:

```
[1,"4/4"],
[1,"2=120"],
[46, "4=155"],
[67, "5/4"],
[68, "4/4"],
[152,""]
```

The output of the program should be the duration of the entire piece in "xm ys" (where x is the number of minutes and y is the number of seconds. You can leave out the "ys" part if there's no spare seconds, but it is not necessary).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

#### Important note!

*Real* artists do not follow the tempo exactly. Only beginners use a metronome to match the exact number of seconds as notated; more experienced musicians know to dynamically speed up or slow down depending on the mood, their personal preference, etcetera. Therefore, it is perfectly acceptable for your answer to be **up to 34% higher or lower** than the "correct" answer. Also, the minimum length of a composition is 2 minutes and 30 seconds.

#### Test cases

1.

```
[1,"4/4"],
[1,"4=120"],
[521,""]
```

The time signature has 4 quarter notes a bar, and 520 bars, so 4*520=2080 quarter notes. There's 120 quarter notes per minute, so 2080/120=17.333 minutes, or 17m 20s.

2.

```
[1,"4/4"],
[1,"8=120"],
[46, "4=155"],
[66, "5/4"],
[76, "6/8"],
[152,""]
```

For the first 45 bars, there's 4 quarter notes a bar, so that's 45*4=180 quarter notes. Now the tempo is 120 8th notes per minute, which is 60 quarter notes per minute, meaning the first bit lasts 180/60=3 minutes.

Then a tempo change: from bar 46 to 67 there's 20 bars of 4/4 (thus 4*20=80 quarter notes), and at 155 quarter notes per minute you add 155/80=1.94 minutes = 1m 56s. Total is 4m 56s.

Then a time signature change: 10 bars of 5 quarter notes per bar = 50 quarter notes. 155/50 = 3.1 minutes = 3m 6s. Total is 8m 2s.

Then another time signature change. 6 eighth notes per bar for 76 bars is 76*6=456 eighth notes. Tempo is still 155 *quarter notes* per minute, which is 310 *eighth notes* per minute. 456/310=1.471 minutes = 1m 28s. Total comes down to 9m 39s.

3.
([The third movement of Shostakovich's second piano concerto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAx-RjiGiHM), you get 5 bytes off if you listen to this while programming <sup><sup>(not really but more people need to listen to Shosty dammit)</sup></sup>)

```
[1, "2/4"],
[1, "4=176"],
[75, "7/8"],
[102, "6/8"],
[103, "7/8"],
[106, "3/8"],
[107, "7/8"],
[109, "2/4"],
[112, "3/4"],
[113, "2/4"],
[116, "3/4"],
[117, "2/4"],
[120, "3/4"],
[121, "2/4"],
[124, "3/4"],
[125, "2/4"],
[155, "7/8"],
[160, "2/4"],
[175, "7/8"],
[180, "2/4"],
[181, "6/8"],
[182, "2/4"],
[186, "7/8"],
[188, "2/4"],
[222, "7/8"],
[225, "2/4"],
[286, "7/8"],
[308, "9/8"],
[309, "7/8"],
[314, "2/4"],
[317, "3/4"],
[318, "2/4"],
[321, "3/4"],
[322, "2/4"],
[325, "3/4"],
[326, "2/4"],
[329, "3/4"],
[330, "2/4"],
[356, ""]
```

Calculation is too long to show here, but it comes down to 4m 47s. The video is 5m 24s, proving my point that this is not an exact rule but rather a guideline.

#### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

#### Sandbox

Does this look like an interesting puzzle? Any tags I miss? Is the +/-34% allowance large enough to matter, or should it be more?

Comment: The "+- 34%" and "at least 2:30 min" are unneccessary for the challenge. They may be relevant for music, but not for programming. I doubt that this allowance will allow you to shave bytes off the task, given that it's straightforward parsing + arithmetic otherwise.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I want to make the allowance relevant, both because it is musically appropriate, and because it would elicit different kinds of answers that approximate the solution. I suppose the arithmetic needs to be more complex before approximate solutions can be made with shorter programs? How about adding accelerando events that change the tempo over time?

Comment: Or maybe I should make a hilariously long list of possible events (e.g. fermata changing the length of a single note, all the different types of ritardando with slightly different slowing down behaviours, etc.) and make it part of the challenge to sort out which ones are relevant to get close enough to the solution?

Comment: I'm not an expert golfer, so I can't say at what level of complexity an approximation gets shorter than just the straightforward calculation. I think the site consensus is for approximative approaches to use precision scoring (How many out of this long list of test cases do you get accurately), because otherwise there is the hidden condition of "for *all* possible valid inputs", which is hard to prove for approximation algorithms.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem Very well, I could generate a list of 100 "compositions" and make the % of properly solved cases part of the score. I guess that would mean adding a different tag? I couldn't find one for "approximation" or direct synonyms of that.

Comment: If you go for the fraction of cases correct method, the tag you want is [tag:test-battery].

Comment: So, we wont include  repeat sign  in this challenge. Am I right?

Comment: @tsh Not at this stage. And if I do, it definitely won't be using the unicode token.

Answer (score 0):

## **Deathmatch Football (Soccer)**

**Idea:**

2 Teams each of 11 Players and 3 Bank Players compete in a match of 90 minutes to find out who's the best. But... it wouldn't be deathmatch with no casualties, so after scoring, there is a chance to die. 
**Better think twice before you shoot...**

**Teams:**

Each Team is represanted as a String of 14 chars (11 + 3). Every char az-AZ is unique to the whole match. So 2 teams could look like this

```
Team1: {"a","c","f","g","j","k","A","D","E","H","I","k","n","o"} //bank: k, n, o
Team2: {"b","d","e","h","i","l","B","C","F","G","J","l","m","P"} //bank: l, m, P
```

**The Game:**

The game lasts for 90 (+3) minutes. Every minute each team has one chance to score a goal. The player who's shooting gets randomly selected. The chance of a player to score a goal is the byte value of the char.

```
Example: "z" has a value of 122, so he has a chance of 122% (>=100%) means he will definetely score
```

If he scores he will die with a chance of his byte value / 2

```
Example: "z" has a value of 122, so he has a chance of 61% to die.
```

**Special Events:**

- At minute 45, 60 and 75 a random player from the bank comes into the team (teams are not limited to 11 players, if no one has died yet)
- If there is a draw at minute 90 OR both teams have less than 5 players, the game lasts for additional 3 minutes (90 + 3)
- If a team has 0 players the game is over

**Result and Rating:**

Once a match is over. Display both teams, the final score, and the top scorer including goals.

```
Team1: {"a","f","A","D","p"}
Team2: {"b","e","h","P"}
Score: 20:18 // So Team1 won
Top Scorer: A=>5
```

The code with less bytes is the winner.

**Extra Notes:**

You are free to choose the form of the output as long as you can clearly see the remianing teams, who won and the top scorer. 
No loopholes, do i need to say that?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 0):

## Double an infinitely long number

You are given a non-negative real number strictly less than 0.5 as an endless stream of digits. Output twice of it in an endless stream of digits.

The exact format is flexible. You may separate digits by any reasonable separator, or don't use separators. You may prepend something representing "0" or "0.", or just omit the integral part. The input and output don't have to be in the same format. But everything must be in base 10, from the most significant digit to less significant digits.

Your code doesn't have to print anything immediately. But if each digit in the input would be given in a finite amount of time, and it is in a state allowing output in your chosen I/O method (so that if you are using a generator, you may assume some code is repeatedly accessing the generator), each digit in the output should also be printed or returned in a finite amount of time.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: I presume the stream of digits is given from largest to smaller place? I think this would be cleaner if we didn't have to deal with a decimal point, say by saying the input starts after the decimal point and is less than 0.5.

Comment: Would it be a valid submission to give a stateful function that takes in a digit, and outputs some a string of digits, so that repeatedly calling it with digits from the stream gives the desired output if concatenated? Or does our code have to handle the read-and-output loop itself?

Comment: @xnor Not sure. I'll accept it if it becomes a standard I/O method for reading/writing lists.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiplicative Digital Root

The Digital root of a number is found by iteratively summing its digits until you end up with a single number (e.g. 99 -> 18 -> 9)

The *multiplicative* digital root is found by iteratively multiplying the digits (e.g. 99 -> 81 -> 8)

## The Challenge

Print out the digital root of all numbers 0..99 inclusive. Note that this is based on https://oeis.org/A031347, and the first 10 numbers (0-9) are treated without leading 0s.

## Input

None

## Output

In any sensible format:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 
0, 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 4, 
0, 4, 8, 2, 6, 0, 8, 6, 6, 8, 
0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 
0, 6, 2, 8, 8, 0, 8, 8, 6, 0, 
0, 7, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8, 8, 0, 8, 
0, 8, 6, 8, 6, 0, 6, 0, 8, 4,
0, 9, 8, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 4, 8,
```

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Sandbox comments

- [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153277/the-non-zero-digital-product-challenge) is the only related challenge I could find, but it doesn't ask the same thing.
- Would this be better/more interesting as a "calculate the multiplicative digital root of the input" challenge?

Comment: no, because `0`,`1`..`9` are single-digit numbers. `00`, `01`..`09` would make the first row zero, but based on the OEIS sequence (https://oeis.org/A031347) I want to treat them as shown

Comment: Ah ok, I misread it as a multiplication table instead of just a sequence of `0..n`. Ignore my now deleted comment. So we just output the first `100` numbers in the (0-based) sequence? Would outputting the 1-based sequence be allowed (`1..100` instead of `0..99`)? If not np, but I could save a byte in my prepared solution if it would be allowed. :)

Comment: Sorry yeah, I've just formatted it that way for clarity. No, 0-99 was the challenge I had in mind. Alternatively would this be a better challenge if you had to calculate the multiplicative digital root given an input (arbitrary-length integer)? Or should I just propose both challenges?

Comment: Either is fine by me, but not both. If the single input would already exist as challenge, this ranged one would simply use those answers with a `0..99` map around it (which is also what I do in my current answer in my language of choice: calculating the multiplicative digital root of an input is 3 bytes; adding a range `0..99` map around it is 4 more bytes).

Comment: The challenge you linked to is the same except that it doesn't require wrapping the thing in a for loop. I believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate it wouldn't be a for loop, but rather recursion (or a while), right? Anyway, the challenge as written here currently asks for the whole set - so I'd say that's substantially different to the linked challenge

Comment: I personally see it as closely related instead of a dupe @mypronounismonicareinstate, although I agree parts of the answers could be reused. That other challenge asks: remove all zeroes, and take the product of the remaining digits. Whereas this challenge asks: for the numbers in the range `0..99`; reduce by taking the product of its digits until a single digit remains. In 05AB1E for example, that other challenge is `0KSP` and this challenge is `т<ÝεΔSP`. The `SP` part (split to digits, take product) is similar. Both challenges are rather trivial in most languages, though - even non-golf langs

Answer (score 0):

## Walk N Spaces on a Game Board

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

This challenge is inspired by Touhou Cannonball, a mobile game that includes a board game element similar to Mario Party, except for the fact that movement isn't restricted to one particular direction.

[image: A Touhou Cannonball board.]

#### Movement

On your turn, a six-sided dice is rolled to determine how many spaces to move. For each of those spaces, you can move to any adjacent space, as long as you do not backtrack to the space you were on in a previous move.

For example, if you roll a 2 and start from space `[2]` in the following graph, you can move left twice to space `[0]` or right twice to space `[4]`, but you cannot move once left and once right to land on space `[2]` again, because you traveled across the same edge in two consecutive moves.

```
0<->1<->2<->3<->4
```

You *can* move to a previously visited space, as long as you aren't "backtracking" to that space -- if you roll a 4 on the following graph starting from space `[0]`, you can land on `[0]` by going in a circle around the graph with the move `[0]->[1]->[2]->[3]->[0]`.

```
0<-->1
^    ^
|    |
v    v
3<-->2
```

Some graphs may have some directed edges. If your graph is `[0]-->[1]`, you can move from `[0]` to `[1]`, but not the other way around.

#### The Challenge

Given any appropriate directed graph structure (incidence matrix, adjacency list, etc.), a starting position, and a number of spaces to move, output all possible positions you can move to.

#### Examples

Example inputs are zero-indexed in the format `starting position, number of spaces, adjacency list`. I will also have the visual graph included for better visualization. (More to be added later)

```
Input: 2, 5, [ [1,2], [0,3], [3,4], [1,6], [2,5], [4,6], [3,5] ]
0<----->1
^       ^
|       |
|       v
2------>3
^       ^
|       |
v       v
4<->5<->6

Output: [1,2,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How fair are my dice?

*(Inspired by a dream I recently had regarding Mario Party. This is not fully fleshed-out yet.)*

Given a pair of dice, e.g., `[[1,1,2,2,3,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]`, output how "closely" they resemble a pair of standard 1-6 dice (i.e., `[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]`) in terms of distribution of numbers when rolled.

Comment: Is the input always a pair of six-sided dice or can they have a variety of face counts? Sorted? How would `[[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]` compare considering it'd have the same distribution curve?

Comment: You need to flesh out details on how this should be measured. Do I go by simulation? Do I base the distribution on the total of each pair of rolls? What is "closely"? Sum of squared error?

Answer (score 0):

## [A game of putting lines through dots.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196670/game-of-putting-lines-through-dots)

Answer (score 0):

## Rate your brevity

This challenge is to produce a script that will accept a string as input, and generate a score for it using the rules defined below. Your score is the return value of your program given its own source as input.

**The first scoring system**

Each additional unique character has an escalating penalty to your score.

The first unique character is worth `-1`
The second unique character is worth `-2`
The third unique character is worth `-3`
etc...

**The second scoring system**

Each repetition of a given character incurs a further escalating penalty to your score.

The first usage of a given character incurs no additional penalty
The second usage of a given character incurs an additional penalty of `-1`
The third usage of a given character incurs an additional penalty of `-2`
The fourth usage of a given character incurs an additional penalty of `-3`
etc...

**e.g.**

- The code `abc` would have a score of `-6`
- The code `aabc` would have a score of `-7`
- The code `aaaabc` would have a score of `-12`

**Rules**

- Your score starts at `0`
- The highest score for a given language wins.

**Test**

The below Stack snippet will parse a string according to the rules defined above and generate the score.

```js
function testScore() {
  var score = 0,
      counter = 0,
      input = document.getElementById('code').value,
      x,
      y,
      instances = {},
      keys;
    
  input = input.split('');

  for(x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
    if(typeof instances[input[x]] == 'undefined') {
      instances[input[x]] = 0;
      score -= ++counter;
    }
    
    instances[input[x]]++;
  }

  keys = Object.keys(instances);
  for(x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < instances[keys[x]]; y++) {
      score -= y;
    }
  }

  alert('Your score is:\n' + String(score));
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return testScore(this);">
  <div>
    <textarea id="code" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Generate score</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate some pointers on what tags to use for this one - it's similar to code golf but isn't quite code golf.

Comment: [Similar but a slightly different scoring system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/unique-is-cheap)

Comment: This is [two challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384): First, reading your own source code. Second, creating the score for an input string. In addition, the condition of "Parse yourself" [is a non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002). In this case, it's definetly bad because it forces the two separate challenges approach onto people. I understand why you want to exclude `print -45`, but right now, the whole quine-except-not-really thing doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem Respectfully I disagree with your assertion that reading the source code is a challenge; I'm very explicit that any means of getting your source code in is acceptable, even copy/pasting it as a command line argument. The parsing of your own code - I thought it might encourage people to golf in a way they may not be used to due to the escalating penalties involved in the scoring system.

Comment: If you don't want the source code reading to be part of the challenge, then don't write things like it is. Really just say `Takes a string as input and outputs the uniqueness score` and `Your score is the return value of your program when given its own source as input`.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I take your point, your phrasing is definitley better than what I originally had.

Answer (score 0):

## Nash equilibrium of 2-player 3-choice zero-sum game [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory)

### Background

In a 2-player single finite game, a [**Nash equilibrium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) (NE) is a pair of strategies chosen by both players where neither has an incentive to deviate from their own strategy. For example, here is a [payoff matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-form_game) of two players \$ A,B \$ where each player has two possible pure strategies \$ X,Y \$:

$$
\matrix{
A \backslash B & X & Y \\
X & 3 \backslash 3 & 0 \backslash 0 \\
Y & 0 \backslash 0 & 2 \backslash 2
}
$$

In this game, if \$ A \$ chooses \$ X \$, \$ B \$ should also choose \$ X \$ because it will give \$ B \$ the best outcome. Likewise, if \$ B \$ chooses \$ X \$, \$ A \$ should also choose \$ X \$. Therefore, \$ (X,X) \$ is a NE. We can observe \$ (Y,Y) \$ is also a NE; although it gives less outcome than \$ (X,X) \$ for both players, there is no reason to select \$ X \$ when the opponent selects \$ Y \$.

But a strategy can also be a mixed strategy, i.e. choosing one of the pure strategies with some chance. Let's take a mixed strategy \$ S = \frac25X+\frac35Y \$. If \$ A \$ takes \$ S \$, \$ B \$'s *expected outcome* is always \$ \frac65 \$, regardless of \$ B \$'s strategy (either pure or mixed). In this case, \$ B \$ has zero incentive to deviate from whatever strategy \$ B \$ is already taking. The same can be said for \$ B \$ taking \$ S \$, so \$ (S, S) \$ is also a NE.

[**Nash's existence theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Nash's_Existence_Theorem) states that every game has at least one Nash equilibrium, either pure or mixed. Note that a game may have many (possibly infinitely many) NEs.

### Challenge

In this challenge, we consider **2-player 3-choice zero-sum games**, where each player has three possible pure strategies, and the sum of the two players' outcomes is always zero. The payoff matrix of such a game might look like this:

$$
\matrix{
A \backslash B & R & P & S \\
R & 0 \backslash 0 & -1 \backslash 1 & 1 \backslash -1 \\
P & 1 \backslash -1 & 0 \backslash 0 & -1 \backslash 1 \\
S & -1 \backslash 1 & 1 \backslash -1 & 0 \backslash 0
}
$$

Since it is a zero-sum game, we can omit the payoffs of \$ B \$:

$$
\matrix{
A & R & P & S \\
R & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
P & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
S & -1 & 1 & 0
}
$$

This game is equivalent to Rock-Paper-Scissors, and the only NE is, as we all know, mixed \$ (\frac13R + \frac13P + \frac13S,\frac13R + \frac13P + \frac13S) \$.

The challenge is to **find at least one of the Nash equilibria, given the payoff matrix for player** \$ A \$. Remember that a Nash equilibrium is a pair of \$ (\text{strategy of } A,\text{strategy of } B) \$.

For an outline of finding a mixed-strategy NE, refer to [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564233/how-to-compute-all-nash-equilibria-in-an-example-of-a-3x3-matrix). Also related: [why some games don't have mixed-strategy NE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113455/calculating-nash-equilibrium-in-mixed-strategy-in-a-game-where-a-nash-equilibriu?rq=1).

### Input and output

The input is a 3-by-3 matrix of integers which represent the payoff matrix for player \$ A \$. You can assume the magnitude of each integer won't exceed 100, and you can take the numbers in any order of your choice.

The output is a pair of strategies in the form of \$ (a_XX+a_YY+a_ZZ, b_XX+b_YY+b_ZZ) \$ where \$ a_i \$ and \$ b_i \$ are the chances of selecting one of the strategies. You don't need to format the output; outputting the 6 numbers \$ a_X,a_Y,a_Z,b_X,b_Y,b_Z \$ is fine. If you want to output a pure strategy, you can do something like \$ (1, 0, 0) \$.

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Matrix: (classic RPS)
  0  -1   1
  1   0  -1
 -1   1   0
NE: A's strategy = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3), B's strategy = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)
--------------------------------------
Matrix: (scored RPS)
  0  -5   1
  5   0  -2
 -1   2   0
NE: A's strategy = (2/8, 1/8, 5/8), B's strategy = (2/8, 1/8, 5/8)
--------------------------------------
Matrix: (dumb game, pure strategy NE example)
  0   1   2
 -1   0   0
 -2   0   0
NE: A's strategy = (1, 0, 0), B's strategy = (1, 0, 0)
--------------------------------------
Matrix: (asymmetric game example, infinitely many NEs)
  2  -1   3
  0   3  -1
 -2  -3   0
NE: A's strategy = (1/2, 1/2, 0),
    B's strategy = any triple (x, y, z) that satisfies
                   x + 2z = 2y, x + y + z = 1, 0 <= x,y,z <= 1
--------------------------------------
Matrix: (asymmetric game example, one mixed NE)
  2  -1   4
  0   3  -1
 -2  -3   0
NE: A's strategy = (1/2, 1/2, 0), B's strategy = (2/3, 1/3, 0)
```

---

### Meta

- Is the challenge clear enough?
- Can anyone confirm the test cases are correct?
- Actually, calculating a NE involves a lot of subtleties, e.g. [strict dominance elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance) and [mixed NEs for a game with unequal number of strategies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72341). Should I include these in the post?
- [game-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory) is not yet an existing tag. Is it appropriate to create one? Are there any other suitable tag(s)?

Answer (score 0):

## Bunda-Gerth parser for abstract APL-family language [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [apl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apl)

### Background

APL has four kinds of tokens: arrays, functions, monadic operators (mops) and dyadic operators (dops).<sup>1)</sup> Let's denote them **A** (arrays), **F** (functions), **M** (mops), and **D** (dops) respectively. Usually when programming in APL, we use a mental model like this:

- Strand notation: `A A ... A -> A`
- Monadic function application: `F A -> A`
- Dyadic function application: `A F A -> A`
- Mop with left operand: `(A|F) M -> F`
- Dop with both operands: `(A|F) D (A|F) -> F`
- Mops and dops bind first from left to right (producing functions), and then function applications are evaluated from right to left

But J.D.Bunda and J.A.Gerth proposed [another way to parse APL expressions](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_parse.htm). In this method, each (ordered) pair of tokens is assigned a *binding strength* and a *resulting token*. Below is the translation of the above mental model. Note that some token pairs do not bind at all, and we have a new token type **AF**, which stands for a function with bound left argument.

```
Binding strength | Token pair(s) -> result
--------------------------------------------
               5 | A A -> A        # Strand notation
               4 | D (A|F) -> M    # Dop + Right operand -> Mop
               3 | (A|F) M -> F    # Left operand + Mop  -> Function
               2 | A F -> AF       # Array + Function    -> Left-bound function
               1 | (F|AF) A -> A   # Function + Array    -> Array
```

Then the actual parsing proceeds as follows: given a stream of tokens,

1. Evaluate the binding strengths between adjacent tokens.
2. Select the token pair whose binding strength is the rightmost local "peak", i.e. the `x y` pair in `w x y z` satisfying `wx < xy >= yz`. `w` and/or `z` can be empty. Note that the leftmost pair is bound first in `A A ... A`.
3. Group the pair and produce a new token as specified in the transition table.
4. Repeat from 1 until single token is left (successful parse) or no more reduction is possible (syntax error).

### Challenge

Given a list of tokens, output the **order of binding** (refer to the I/O section for specification) using the transition table and algorithm described above.

### Input and output

The input is a non-empty list of A/F/M/D tokens. You may use any number or single character to represent a token. You may assume that the input will always parse successfully, and the input won't contain any parentheses (since it isn't specified in the table above).

For the output, the **order of binding** represents in which order each gap between the tokens is closed:

```
Given the tokens:       A A F M A
Assign each gap an ID:   w x y z
Binding strength:        5 2 3 0
Rightmost local peak:       F M
Bind them first:        A A (F M) A     -> y = 1
Bind A-A next:         (A A) (F M) A    -> w = 2
Bind A-F next:        ((A A) (F M)) A   -> x = 3
Bind AF-A last:      (((A A) (F M)) A)  -> z = 4

Given the tokens:       A A F M A
The order of binding:    2 3 1 4  (the answer)
```

Note that, if the input contains `L` tokens, the answer is always a permutation of `1..L-1` (or `0..L-2` if you choose zero-based numbering).

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Input:  A A A A A
Output:  1 2 3 4
-----------------------------
Input:  A F F A A F F A
Output:  6 7 5 2 3 4 1
-----------------------------
Input:  A  F D A A  M  A A D F M F A
Output:  11 9 8 7 10 12 3 4 2 5 6 1
```

### Footnote

1. An actual implementation of APL has some special tokens, e.g. dot `.`, jot `∘`, and index notation `[x]`. We ignore them here for simplicity.

Comment: Maybe an easy answer format is simply inserting the order of binding? `A F F A A F F A` → `((A F) (F (((A A) F) (F A))))` → `((A5F)7(F6(((A1A)2F)4(F3A))))` and maybe even returning the permutation vector `5 7 6 1 2 4 3`?

Comment: @Adám That could work, but I don't think it's any easier to produce than a fully structured output. Also, alternative algorithms can produce the same tree with different binding order.

Comment: It will be really hard to verify with the broad output allowance. Maybe just require fully parenthesising?

Comment: @Adám IMO it's not a problem, as long as the answers specify which output format they're using.

Comment: On second thought, I decided to emphasize the algorithm itself (over the resulting parse tree).

Answer (score 0):

This is a repost of the [underspecified challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/remove-duplicates-from-one-list).

### Task:

Remove all duplicates from one list of integers. A list is simply a sequence of connected values that allows the same values to be stored at different positions in this sequence.

If an item was found to be the same value as another item in this list, keep the first occurence of the item and remove the second (third and so on...) occurence of the item.

### Input/Output

You may write a function or full program that takes a list as an input and returns a remove-duplicated list as an output.

### Rules:

- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest answer wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Join two file paths

A *file path* consists of letters a-z separated by slashes `/`. Your task is to join two paths as follows:

- If the second path doesn't start with `/`, concatenate them with exactly one `/` in between.
- If the second path starts with `/`, just output it.

For example,

```
/User/Desktop   temp/file   ->  /User/Desktop/temp/file
/User/Desktop/  temp/file   ->  /User/Desktop/temp/file
/User/Desktop   /temp/file  ->  /temp/file
/User/Desktop/  /temp/file  ->  /temp/file
relative/path   more/path/  ->  relative/path/more/path
```

You may assume the inputs don't contain two consecutive slashes, but they may start or end with a slash. Each input with be nonempty and not just a slash. You may use backslash `\` in places of slash `/`.

**Sandbox:** Is this too boring? Too likely a built-in?

Comment: (Replacing with a bit cleaner proof) Here's a neat way that I think works to show that anti-commutativity implies any product equals zero for \$S=\mathbb{Z}\$. We have \$ a \* b =  a \* (b+0) = - (a \* b) - (a \* 0)\$, so \$ a \* b \$ is half of \$-(a \* 0)\$ in the standard integer sense. This implies that the product \$ a \* b\$ doesn't depend in \$b\$ and so is just a function of \$a\$, say \$ a \* b=A\$. Then, the anti-commutativity rule \$a \* (b+c) = -(a\*b + a\*c) \$ gives \$A = - (A+A)\$ so \$A=0\$, and thus any product is \$0\$.

Answer (score 0):

## String Blockify™ a Hexagon

> an obvious rip-off of [Hexagonify™ a String Block](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197080/hexagonify-a-string-block)

#### What is Hexagonification?

Hexagonification is a transformation that creates a hexagon with 3 copies of a rectangle block™, each skewed to the right by 30 degrees and then rotated by 0, 120 and 240 degrees respectively, as shown in the following image. A triangle hole may appear in the middle, but that isn't a great deal.

[image: diagram of hexagonification]

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that receives a hexagonified block of string™ as an input and outputs the original string block™.
[image: diagram of string blockification]
The input and output formats are flexible. You may receive a single string, a list of lines or a 2D array as input, and output a single string or a list of lines. You may have leading/trailing spaces on each line and leading/trailing newlines, provided that the block is properly formed. See Sample IO for how the blocks™ should be positioned.

#### Sample IO

Input:

```
   3 x 3
  e s q u
 u r a r e
3 q a a s 3
 x s r q x
  3 e u 3
```

Output:

```
3x3
squ
are
```

Input:

```
   l o n g e r . . . . .
  . r e c t a n g u l a r
 r . b l o c k . . . . . .
. a .                 b r l
 . l .               l e o
  . u .             o c n
   . g .           c t g
    . n k         k a e
     r a c       . n r
      e t o     . g .
       g c l   . u .
        n e b . l .
         o r . a .
          l . r .
```

Output:

```
longer.....
rectangular
block......
```

Input:

```
        v b
       8 e l
      x l r o
     2 a   t c
    k c     i k
   c i       c 2 
  o t         a x
 l r           l 8
b e l a c i t r e v
 v 8 x 2 k c o l b
```

Output:

```
vb
el
ro
tc
ik
c2
ax
l8
```

Input:

```
 1 . l i n e
e           1
 n         .
  i       l
   l     i
    .   n
     1 e
```

Output:

```
1.line
```

Input:

```
      1
     e .
    n   l
   i     i
  l       n
 .         e
1 e n i l . 1
```

Output:

```
1
.
l
i
n
e
```

#### Scoring

Your score will be the area of the source code as a String Block™. Assuming your code can just fit inside a rectangle of width \$w\$ and height \$h\$, the score will be:

$$w \cdot h$$

#### Winning Criteria

The submission with the lowest score in each language wins.

Comment: The obvious problem here is that the reverse challenge is "cluttered" with the information being available three times. The solutions won't profit from the structure being a full hexagon, one of the three skewed rectangles is enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Joyous Kwanzaa!

Kwanzaa is an annual week-long celebration of African culture and history, and takes place on December 26 to January 1. During Kwanzaa it is traditional to light the seven candles of a *kinara*, one on each day. The middle candle is lit first, followed by the rest of the candles from left to right.

### Challenge

Your challenge will be to write a program or function that when given ASCII art (in any convenient format) of candles on a kinara (as specified below), some of which may be lit, will return or output a ASCII art of what the kinara would look like on the next day.

### Specification

A kinara will contain of seven even columns of equal length with equal spacing between them, representing the candles. The candles will be constructed with some consistent printable, non-whitespace ASCII character.

Some of the candles might have a flame above them, which will be represented by a single printable, non-whitespace ASCII character, possibly the same as the candle's character. If no candles are lit, there will be an empty line above the candles.

Here is an example of a kinara ASCII art:

```
*     *
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
```

### Input/Output

The input will be a kinara with seven candles, 0-6 of them lit according to the rule (middle candle first, then the rest from left to right).

The output will be a kinara with candles and flames identical to the input kinara, but with one more lit candle than the input. The extra candle will be lit according to the rule. If no candles are lit in the input, you may use any character for the flame.

You may assume the input is valid according to the specification given. You may assume the input has no trailing or leading whitespace in any of the lines, but trailing or leading whitespace is acceptable in the output as long as the kinara has the proper shape.

### Examples

In/out:

```
*     *
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |

* *   *
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
```

In/out:

```
** *
|||||||

****
|||||||
```

In/out:

```
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 6

5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

In/out:

```
               # pretend this is an empty line
q q q q q q q

      0
q q q q q q q
```

### Rules

- No standard loopholes
- Shortest code in bytes wins

### Questions

- Is this too complicated? If so how could I simplify it?
- Is the wording unclear?
- Is this too similar to an existing challenge? I found another [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64174/festival-of-ascii-art-lights) which involves creating a menorah, but this one takes candles as input instead of a date.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Answer (score 0):

## Hit the most Balloons with one Arrow

You got 1 arrow to hit as much balloons as possible. A common way to solve this, is to mark the tangent points of every balloon and project the angles on the source's position. As seen in the following image this has been down already. The task is now to find the optimal and angle-centered solution to hit the most Balloons.

[image: Balloon]

**The Input:**

A json array of length 360 (for every 1° one entry) representating the number of Balloons hit at this angle.

JSON: https://pastebin.com/raw/Rd8g7Z6J

**The Task:**

Find an algorithm that solves the task with the following requirements:

- return the number of most hits
- return the max range of angles with the most hits
- return the the centered angle of this range
- there are no format restrictions how you are returning the values, it could be 3 prints or an array... whatever, as long as it is clear to see whats the hits, range and center

**Solution of given JSON:**

- Most Hits: 6
- Range: 358 - 0
- Center: 359

**Notes:**

Remember its a circle, so you need to check if the range crosses the 360°/0° mark!!! A range can be like 300° - 10° for example.

For simplicity the angles are 0° - 359° as 360° would be 0°.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Comment: That's a lot of words and a picture wasted because your challenge is really just "Find the longest max-value sequence in the array", which is probably a duplicate. I think the challenge would be a lot better if you actually had to calculate this angle distribution from an input of balloon coordinates and a size.

Answer (score 0):

## Potentially Prime Punch-Card Patterns [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

---

### Punch-cards

Let us define a punch-card to be a set of 'open' and 'closed' holes which can slide over the positive integer number line:

```
    _________________________
   |   ___     ___     ___   | -->
   |  |   |   |   |   |   |  |
1  |  | 3 |   | 5 |   | 7 |  |  9   10  11  12  13  14
   |  |___|   |___|   |___|  |
   |_________________________| -->
```

When the first open hole is on the integer \$ p \$, then this punchcard (as it slides across the number line) yields the integers \$p, p+2,\$ and \$p+4\$. So, we can represent this card as the set \$\{0, 2, 4\}\$.

### Admissibility

Given a punch-card we may wonder whether it is possible to slide the card to such a position that only prime numbers are under the 'open' holes.

Clearly, for \$\{0, 2, 4\}\$, we can position the punch-card to make 3, 5, and 7 visible. However, this is the only solution. Taking each element modulo 3  yields \$\{0, 2, 1\}\$, which contains every possible remainder under division by 3, so one visible integer must be divisible by 3. But we only want primes, and so 3 itself must be visible; this leaves a finite number of possible positions, of which only one is a valid solution.

More generally, if there exists a prime \$q\$ such that **every** integer \$0 \le n < q\$ appears in the punch-card set modulo \$q\$, then the punch-card is **inadmissible** and has a finite number of positions where all visible integers are prime: as we are bounded by the condition that \$q\$ must be visible. We can place \$q\$ in each hole in turn, and perform primality tests to count the valid solutions.

However, if there exists no such \$q\$, then the punch-card is **admissible** and we cannot assume there are finite solutions; the [K-Tuple Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) in fact hypothesizes that every admissible punch-card can assume **infinitely many** positions where all visible integers are prime.

### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a list of ordered positive integers representing a punch-card set, outputs the number of positions the punch-card can assume where all visible integers are prime. If the set is admissible, then give a distinct output such as `-1`, `null`, `Inf` - anything that is not a non-negative integer.

### Test Cases

Coming soon.

---

### Meta

There is a related challenge - [testing for admissible sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89786/testing-for-admissible-sequences). However, I believe this is distinct enough to be a duplicate as rather than being a simple [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), if a set is admissible this program will have to then try different positions of the punch-card and count the valid solutions; whereas the previous challenge considers admissible sets in isolation, this challenge applies it to prime numbers.

Comment: Given that the admissibility test is already a challenge, how about you split off the two-challenge and special case part: The input can be assumed to be an admissible sequence, the task is simply finding the positions resulting in valid solutions.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem i just feel as though that it is much less interesting to golf, and returning the distinct different output would open more interesting golfing opportunities.

Comment: Handling special cases is very rarely interesting to golf, for a quite simple reason: Checking if the special case is present requires bytes. Being told the simple case is the case saves those bytes.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem but for there to be more _golfing opportunities_, don't there have to be more bytes to golf?

Comment: Not really. The issue is that for multiple task challenges, the byte count is 90% of the time optimal_bytes(task1)+optimal_bytes(task2). Often, one of the tasks is considerably longer to golf, to the point where optimizing the other task is almost irrelevant because it's so small compared to the other. Therefore, the site consensus is to split challenges into their individual components as much as possible, and especially avoid input validation, because it's boring and requires lots of bytes.

Comment: But it's not input validation in the sense of there being erroneous or invalid inputs: it's just that the answer to the question "how many prime positions does this have?" may be 0,1,2..., and also (probably) infinity.

Answer (score 0):

## How many ways can I count on n?

By using addition of natural numbers `{1, 2, 3...}` and multiplication of natural numbers *larger than 1*, we can reach the same outcome in several ways. For example `4 = 2 x 2` but also: `4 = 2 + 1 + 1`. Using [normal mathematical operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), there are actually 6 ways to express 4 and 9 ways to express 5.

Since addition is commutative, `a + b` is counted as the same solution as `b + a`. The same holds for multiplication. So `7 = 1 + 2 x 3` is the same solution as `7 = 3 x 2 + 1`.

The (trivial) solution `n` (using no addition or multiplication) is also counted as one of the solutions of `n`.

Multiplication with `1` is forbidden, because you can do this infinitely.

### Task

For a given input `n`, output `c(n)`, which is defined as the number of ways `n` can be uniquely expressed using zero, one or more additions and multiplications of natural numbers, using normal mathematical operator precedence and without multiplication with 1.

### Rules

- Input and output are integers (your program should at least support input and output in the range of 1 up to 32767)
- Invalid input (0, floats, strings, negative values, etc.) may lead to unpredictable output, errors or (un)defined behaviour.
- Default [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answers in bytes wins

### Final note

I can think of several ways to approach this problem. I think it's interesting to see how the different approaches impact the length of the solution.

### Sandbox questions

- Please let me know if this task/problem is stated clear enough.
- Please let me know if there are any loopholes that I should cover in the question.
- I intentionally omitted more examples (because I hope contesters will think about solutions rather than just reproduce an OEIS sequence; although I'm not sure if this question had an OEIS sequence).
- I will tag this question with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Answer (score 0):

### Morse with Binary [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [morse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morse) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

For every input string (**in ASCII, containing only lowercase alphabetic characters**), output the *alphabetic* string converted from Morse code to Binary code.

In this case we are assuming that `.` is 0 and `-` is 1.

### How to do the conversion

For reference, here are a few Morse code libraries:

```
a .-
b -...
c -.-.
d -..
e .
f ..-.
g --.
h ....
i ..
j .---
k -.-
l .-..
m --
n -.
o ---
p .--.
q --.-
r .-.
s ...
t -
u ..-
v ...-
w .--
x -..-
y -.--
z --..
```

What's amazing about those codes is that the code length never exceeds 4 codes.

And now we are trying to cofuse binary with Morse code. First let's convert `sample` to morse code:

```
... .- -- .--. .-.. .
```

And consider the whole thing as a binary:

```
.... ---. --.. -...
```

Here is an alternative table for mapping the characters:

```
a ....
b ...-
c ..-.
d ..--
e .-..
f .-.-
g .--.
h .---
i -...
j -..-
k -.-.
l -.--
m --..
n --.-
o ---.
p ----
```

The result of this operation, after conversion, is `aomi`. You are never going to end up with a letter past `p`.

Comment: What if there is a group of characters remaining? Input: e, Output: ?

Answer (score 0):

## *Quine Generator Generator...* of any* length! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [meta-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-golf)

A *Quine Generator Generator...* is a quine when the input is empty or 0. Otherwise, for any other sufficiently large positive integer input, it should print a *Quine Generator Generator...* of that specified length (in the same language, same options).

Let S be the (most likely theoretically infinite) set of *Quine Generator Generator...* you can generate from your initial *Quine Generator Generator...*.

Your score is the smallest N such that any *Quine Generator Generator...* in S can generate a *Quine Generator Generator...* of length N or longer (for reasonably sized N).

Input can be from standard input or as an argument of a function.

Lowest score wins.

## Sandbox Meta:

Typically, code is scored by bytes, but now the length would depend on how that is interpreted, since it is included in the description of the question. Hence would it be a problem to put: "You may choose to define characters in terms of bytes or characters (should they differ) for purposes of the program length and scoring purposes."

Answer (score 0):

## Integer Keys and Duplicates

Given a list/vector of positive integers, write a function to check the following conditions in as few bytes as possible.

1. Take the first integer (the key, or k1) and check that the next k1 values have no duplicate values, excluding k1.
2. Take the last integer (the second key, or k2) and check that the k2 values before k2 have no duplicate values, excluding k2.

Note that both keys, k1 and k2, are elements of the list/vector as either key could contain the other.

Also, k1 and/or k2 can be greater than the number of integers within the list, which means you should check every element of the list besides the given key for duplicates, excluding the key.

If both steps return True, return True, else, return False.

#### Test Cases

```
[5,1,2,5,3,4,3] is TRUE because [k1=5][1,2,5,3,4] has no duplicates, nor does [5,3,4] have any duplicates, excluding 3

[6,9,12,15,18,19,8,8,3] is FALSE because [k1=6][9,12,15,18,19,8] has no duplicates while [19,8,8][k2=3] has a duplicate.

[100,100,100,100,101,102,3] is TRUE because [k1=100][100,100,100,101,102,3] has no duplicates, and [100,101,102][k2=3] has no duplicates.

[100,100,100,100,101,102,4] is FALSE. [k1=100][100,100,100,101,102,4] has no duplicates, but [100,100,101,102][k2=4] has duplicates.

[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,3] is TRUE. [k1=6][6,6,6,6,6,6] has no duplicates and [3,3,3][k2=3] has no duplicates.

[1,2] is TRUE (clearly)

[1] is TRUE (clearly)

[] the empty list is also TRUE (if you can make a valid argument why it should be FALSE then I might give it to you)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Drum fill generator

Create a program that generates a drum fill. Your program will output a pattern of `L` (left hand hits), 'R' (right hand hits), and `K` for kick drum hits.

### Rules

- The pattern must never have more than 2 of the same hits consecutively.
- The pattern must be loopable, so it mustn't have more than 2 of the same hits when it loops.
- Your program accepts 1 argument which is the length of the pattern. You can assume this will always be an integer > 0.
- Program output must be random each time it's ran.
- IO can be used with any convenient method.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- This is code-golf, so smallest program wins!

**Example valid output:**

```
RLRRKKLL
LRLLKKLR
LKKRLRKLRRKL
LRLR
```

**Example invalid output:**

```
LRLL // 3 characters when looped
LRLRRRLLR // 3 characters in a row
RRLRLLRR // 4 characters when looped
```

Comment: What's a paradiddle? You should include a description in your question

Comment: How's that? I added more detail on what the rules/patterns are.

Comment: No it must be random each time the program is ran, I'll add that to the rules now, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

## Interpret LCGFuck™ [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

#### Introduction

LCGFuck™ is a Brainfuck-like esoteric programming language invented by me. Inspired by Brainfuck and [linear congruential generators (LCGs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), LCGFuck™ combined both things into one.

An LCG in LCGFuck™ is defined with 5 integers, namely multiplier `a`, adder `b`, modulus `c`, offset `d` and seed `e`. Let `x` be its current state, then the corresponding output will be `x + d`, and the next internal state `x'` of the LCG can be calculated by `x' = (a * x + b) mod c`. All numbers should be non-negative except for `d`. Moreover, `b` and `e` should be in the range `[0, c)`.

#### Technical details

An LCG is defined with 5 numbers, like `12345 678 90 -123 45`. The last two numbers are optional and default to 0.

LCGFuck™ has 3 storage variables, the LCG list, the number list and the number memory. The functions are as follows:

- LCG list: Cyclic list that stores all LCGs created. Every entry is in turn a list of 5 numbers in the order `[a, b, c, d, e]` as notated in the introduction. It has a pointer that controls which LCG is chosen at the moment, and moves in a cycle through the list.
- Number list: Ordinary list that stores the numbers for LCG definition. It can store at most 5 numbers.
- Number memory: A single variable that can be read and written with an input or an LCG output.

LCGFuck™ has 14 operators, namely:

- `\n` (newline): Creates an LCG with the numbers in the order of `[a, b, c(, d(, e))]` and clears the list if the number list contains 3 or more numbers. No-op if the number list contains no more than 2 numbers.
- `<`: Shifts to the previous LCG circularly (back to the last when moving from the first).
- `>`: Shifts to the next LCG circularly (back to the first when moving from the last).
- `+`: Moves the current LCG to the next state (calculates `x' = (a * x + b) mod c`)
- `c`: Prints the output of the current LCG as a character (with the output as the codepoint).
- `n`: Prints the output of the current LCG as a number (with a trailing space)
- `o`: Writes the output of the current LCG to number memory
- `i`: Reads a value from the input and writes it to number memory. There is two input mode, one reading a character one time, and one reading a number one time. **You do not need to implement this operator in this challenge.**
- `s`: Reads the value from number memory and seeds the current LCG with it
- `m`: Reads the value from number memory and pushes it to the number list
- `[]`: Output loop. Executes the loop if the current LCG is non-zero
- `{}`: State loop. Executes the loop if the state of the current LCG is non-zero

An integer, optionally with a negative sign at the front, pushes the number to the number list. Any characters other than the newline `\n` and any of `-0123456789[]{}<>+cimnos` are no-ops.

The code runs linearly from the first characters, except when loop ends are encountered. Loops can be nested but must be paired accordingly from the innermost loop to the outermost loop.

#### Challenge

Write an interpreter, making it as short as possible, that interprets the LCGFuck source code given as the input. **You need not implement the `i` operator in this challenge**. The output should be printed to STDOUT or returned in case of writing a function.

You may assume that your interpreter always receives valid programs, i.e.:

1. An LCG is always defined before any of the commands that manipulate the LCG or the LCG list pointer
2. At any moment the number list contains at most 5 numbers
3. All brackets are paired accordingly

Standard loopholes are forbidden by default.

[Sample implementation with operator `i` (Primality check)](https://tio.run/##tVhtc9pGEP6uX7FlkliKQAbsNg0WZNJMm8lMm2aa6SeiGWRx2BdLJ/VOMngY/XZ3906AcACLuJXHIN3L7vPs3r6Ir@FtqCLJs7wj0im7v58VIsp5KuD3d@9/K6IbO8LhNnCRFfnHImGSRw4sLVite2mmbByE5tfpKXyYbQkFroCJ8DJm0zbk10yAZBHjtwxCEEVyySTMZJqYPW1gsWK1FdF1KMMo31pkAdyGEhSH4bamppe1vnsDmUwjppQXyqvbcT/wVBbzfAITLwkz@xd@9UHkTm3DAMae5z3YFOjFCxiOwOywP@eSiyuPTPwp5SJ/m9sLx3EuLK18lkqwiQKHdIY8HJJ/x1k8BU5L5tc8ZmDnsmC1qa7AudJ6wN1GoWYsjnBsHLTh6AudhocCVJ7K8ArPRHQXxcachnicoeTudwheSc7IBkwaafwp0j4IhWYxB3lLaqyewj5NM6QfRjdGmLgkYa1WG7b/HxePwj7qQ620l4l8gQfaXpygRFtcjrsBvIQFuKhj3AsceE43fRScFjm6E1dVk2c4phib4gg@nQdOBe0p1jPQtg2nnuYOwrwlTxQkT7SfAjBhSSrvKnw3KK/Tu3iCY2/wyCWhvEGI1iq4cMgHik8vZuIqv9a5T8cRhRFNjHnmusHFUfres3yTslAZ8BnYyMCHLrx4gaJHQzjpnph7H@9fnzgHBXY7rwcQKsWvhDKhhMIThtKVpQ/qWGQBuIiYEodOnsRD660mfxjiySWNtedO67Dat@IOUkzWcsNGwZTFPOF5lbW1fjyOrkuatWozYrSQUspM35pgiLQ7h2hvQ@kc4v/QAMYCuzR@EdrqGD7ogrOdRQ2Vtb6I1gA@FepaK0NBUzbjAqPQRmvAjEuVwxmEkmrUPwWXVVGDOMSJvp5IM8pOYayzvTlScx3E9ZJi5uYY1/B8iN/9wIxUfsNhRF@FvF7l1lfFkZchRnvuKUzUzMbw/dGpZO7NXRdNrP0XU3iEqRIg58rREIrpVoybHKTVlQeNnj7uZtSZDuAzKVTaklUexMIYFVIykZMnrHVmiaNxnAXaIqv7s@Cw66NGKKIB/GlU70WBB7HekmhQq1ZA5VPc480lz9mq/FPL8m7VAtgmt9k7CVS9wX4OohEH0ZSD8ex@AntQ4kMLWo9A9RtB9dHp13yGSFMNNpPslqeFWntbNx02fhKAKklDB3pUMtcDh5GMGiEZPUAi2CLfheIYze7Jo20zanYH8EeKbW7dPQhCA8BuJGdVsK9cQUjWDy9XE92aj0xHUT3Uc8pm3yav1Hw8fLDncFjzRnblW2G96tyrMFbcI5q2492GccEOWzNppC8ZwN8ogJRpmahSP5hmggxrcjkdfzbfZBWqIFjoKUUXh3GoRl5VyJv6NtJd9@yc4wHegewbJ6OB/nsfGgbjkyNe55DLeLDujWXuwacQC6AhEnjw64JFRV75N6ZlqGh30sGeo2t4KlO5sLmiYG5DN3A2DNHgWJ1X3NRN1VtsWOxMS8Rss2dPaTL8l0fyX@7lX3qw2wA6cJvz730n/@acgyM5BxVnJqYevE@R3iW@GFH8xGtTrDsbemEhTmlm13j04BRySkwYOjkmJY2WHtRNp1M7vfpVkBbuBV8eCb78f8D3GoEv9ft5raAyKauC2qJTEHNFKlumpFE3aC/awB364WBijZ8tF95XbBUmbZiUwbMlJ81Yet7gDh/ebY5TCwbY0JUTxyyfEPidWicWzZX3q598Jj1kwhP86PQs@oA0Qcfgw2iZujRJj36ajKxytByVqYvDpb/0S2XRbA/O@nhzDr0@/PQazvXgK3j1M/Stpe@7dEX4Z75d1/L9aITX0i1LvMVBn6YjZKh/3Li4v@93z1/9Cw)

#### Sample

***The LCG list need not be printed out.*** It is just for illustration purpose.

1. The "Hello world!" program in LCGFuck™ is as follows:

   ```
   1 29 30 72
   1 3 9 108
   1 1 2 32
   c+c>cc+co>c
   1 8 9 m
   >+c<<c+c+c<+c>>+c
   ```

   - Output: `Hello world!`
   - LCG list after execution:

     ```
     [1, 29, 30, 72, 28]
     [1, 3, 9, 108, 0]
     [1, 1, 2, 32, 1] < Current LCG
     [1, 8, 9, 111, 8]
     ```
2. An example that outputs the values of `x - 16`, where x is the states of the LCG `x' = (19x + 17) mod 32`, starting with seed `x = 4`, until the output is 0:

   ```
   19 17 32 -16 4
   [n+]n
   ```

   - Output: `-12 13 8 9 -4 5 -16 1 4 -3 -8 -7 12 -11 0`
   - LCG list after execution:

     ```
     [19, 17, 32, 16, -16] < Current LCG
     ```
3. An example that outputs all possible values of `5(x + 12)`, where x is the states of the LCG `x' = (5x + 3) mod 8`:

   ```
   5 3 8 12
   5 0 99
   o>s+n<+{o>s+n<+}
   ```

   - Output: `60 75 70 85 80 95 90 65`
   - LCG list after execution:

     ```
     [5, 3, 8, 12, 0] < Current LCG
     [5, 0, 99, 0, 65]
     ```
4. An example illustrating the 3-number restriction of `\n` (the 9 in the 3rd line is pushed to the number list but the LCG is defined before the 9 is pushed):

   ```
   12 34
   56 78
   9
   n
   ```

   - Output: `78`
   - LCG list after execution:

     ```
     [12, 34, 56, 78, 0] < Current LCG
     ```
5. An example that determines whether 97 is a prime:

   ```
   1 -1 97 0 -1
   {o+1 1 m 0 97
   }>{>}o+{o+}<{<}s
   1 1 1 32
   1 4 12 69 4
   1 1 7 78 2
   {<+++++c+c+++++c+++
   <<c>>>{+}}<c++c<c+c+c
   ```

   - Output: `PRIME`
   - LCG list after execution:

     ```
     [1, -1, 97, 0, 0]
     [1, 1, 96, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 95, 0, 2]
     [1, 1, 94, 0, 3]
     [1, 1, 93, 0, 4]
     [1, 1, 92, 0, 5]
     [1, 1, 91, 0, 6]
     [1, 1, 90, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 89, 0, 8]
     [1, 1, 88, 0, 9]
     [1, 1, 87, 0, 10]
     [1, 1, 86, 0, 11]
     [1, 1, 85, 0, 12]
     [1, 1, 84, 0, 13]
     [1, 1, 83, 0, 14]
     [1, 1, 82, 0, 15]
     [1, 1, 81, 0, 16]
     [1, 1, 80, 0, 17]
     [1, 1, 79, 0, 18]
     [1, 1, 78, 0, 19]
     [1, 1, 77, 0, 20]
     [1, 1, 76, 0, 21]
     [1, 1, 75, 0, 22]
     [1, 1, 74, 0, 23]
     [1, 1, 73, 0, 24]
     [1, 1, 72, 0, 25]
     [1, 1, 71, 0, 26]
     [1, 1, 70, 0, 27]
     [1, 1, 69, 0, 28]
     [1, 1, 68, 0, 29]
     [1, 1, 67, 0, 30]
     [1, 1, 66, 0, 31]
     [1, 1, 65, 0, 32]
     [1, 1, 64, 0, 33]
     [1, 1, 63, 0, 34]
     [1, 1, 62, 0, 35]
     [1, 1, 61, 0, 36]
     [1, 1, 60, 0, 37]
     [1, 1, 59, 0, 38]
     [1, 1, 58, 0, 39]
     [1, 1, 57, 0, 40]
     [1, 1, 56, 0, 41]
     [1, 1, 55, 0, 42]
     [1, 1, 54, 0, 43]
     [1, 1, 53, 0, 44]
     [1, 1, 52, 0, 45]
     [1, 1, 51, 0, 46]
     [1, 1, 50, 0, 47]
     [1, 1, 49, 0, 48]
     [1, 1, 48, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 47, 0, 3]
     [1, 1, 46, 0, 5]
     [1, 1, 45, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 44, 0, 9]
     [1, 1, 43, 0, 11]
     [1, 1, 42, 0, 13]
     [1, 1, 41, 0, 15]
     [1, 1, 40, 0, 17]
     [1, 1, 39, 0, 19]
     [1, 1, 38, 0, 21]
     [1, 1, 37, 0, 23]
     [1, 1, 36, 0, 25]
     [1, 1, 35, 0, 27]
     [1, 1, 34, 0, 29]
     [1, 1, 33, 0, 31]
     [1, 1, 32, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 31, 0, 4]
     [1, 1, 30, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 29, 0, 10]
     [1, 1, 28, 0, 13]
     [1, 1, 27, 0, 16]
     [1, 1, 26, 0, 19]
     [1, 1, 25, 0, 22]
     [1, 1, 24, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 23, 0, 5]
     [1, 1, 22, 0, 9]
     [1, 1, 21, 0, 13]
     [1, 1, 20, 0, 17]
     [1, 1, 19, 0, 2]
     [1, 1, 18, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 17, 0, 12]
     [1, 1, 16, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 15, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 14, 0, 13]
     [1, 1, 13, 0, 6]
     [1, 1, 12, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 11, 0, 9]
     [1, 1, 10, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 9, 0, 7]
     [1, 1, 8, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 7, 0, 6]
     [1, 1, 6, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 5, 0, 2]
     [1, 1, 4, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 3, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
     [1, 1, 1, 32, 0]
     [1, 4, 12, 69, 0] < Current LCG
     [1, 1, 7, 78, 4]
     ```

#### Winning criteria

Since this is a code-golf challenge, the shortest solution for every language wins.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm stepping down [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

You are given 4 positive integers: volume of the first container (`v1`), volume of the second container (`v2`), volume of the liquid in the first container (`l1`), and volume of the liquid in the second container (`l2`). Your task is to move (or "step down", if appropriate) some of the liquid from container 1 to container 2, making the amount of empty space in the containers equal to each other, outputting how much liquid should be moved.

### An example

Here is an example of some possible input (formatted for the ease of test cases. The input isn't formatted.):

```
8 11
6  5
```

Here, you need to make sure that the differences between the volumes and the containers are equal. Currently the difference is not equal:

```
  8 11
- 6  5
======
   6 2
```

So we need to try to make them equal, by taking some of the values in one container to another container:

```
  8 11
- 4  7
======
  4  4
```

After you have succeeded, output how much liquid you need to take from container 1 to container 2. Therefore the above example should output `2`.

### Test cases

```
15 16
 9  2
```

We move into this state:

```
 15 16
- 5  6
======
 10 10
```

Therefore `4` is the expected result.

### Test case #2

```
16 12
13  1
```

We move into this state:

```
 16 12
- 9  5
======
  7  7
```

Therefore `4` is the expected output.

### Test case #3

```
20 12
10 2
```

Moved:

```
 20 12
-10 2
======
 10 10
```

Therefore `0` is the expected output.

### Rules

- The test cases will be made so that the result is always possible as a positive integer. The result will **never** be a decimal.
- Input can be taken in any convenient and reasonable format.
- Output can be given in any convenient and reasonable format.
- The input string will be made so that a moving is always possible without involving decimals or negative numbers. Also there will not be more liquid than how much a container can hold.
- Of course, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer in each language consisting of the fewest number of bytes wins. Happy golfing!
- An extra restriction for the test cases: you can assume that there is always going to be space available in the second container. So a test case like this:

```
10 2
 2 2
```

is not going to be a valid testcase.

Comment: So, it just calculate `abs(v1-l1-v2+l2)/2`? It seems trivial to me. And what should I do if the calculate result is not an integer?

Comment: May I assume the solution always exits? What should I do if input is `v1=10,l1=2,v2=2,l2=2`?

Comment: The test cases will not contain calculations that yield decimal results; also you can assume that there is always enough empty space in the second container to move the liquid.

Comment: I find the challenge title confusing. Please change it.

Comment: @Beefster [The challenge is already posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198097/move-my-liquid-to-make-me-equal), and after [at least 35 people agreed with you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198097/move-my-liquid-to-make-me-equal#comment471280_198097), someone else [changed the title](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/198097/2). @ a'_': please edit this Sandbox post so it only contains the title and link to the posted challenge and delete it from the Sandbox please (as mentioned in bold in the "What is the Sandbox?" post at the top).

Answer (score 0):

## He. Might. Go. All. The. Way. Touchdown!

[in-progress]

**Premise:**

In American Football, a team has to drive up the field to their opponent's end-zone to score points. But here's the catch, they have 4 tries (called downs) to go at least 10 yards to gain a new set of downs. They repeat this until they score a Touchdown, or until they fail to get 10 yards and (at least in this challenge) punt it away or go for a Field Goal.

Your task is to simulate such a drive.

**Challenge:**

You are to output the state of each down, i.e. which down it is, how far to the next down (or the end-zone), and where the ball is. Football location counts up from a team's end-zone (0yd line) up to the 50yd line (the middle), then back down to 0 for the opponent's end-zone.

We differentiate the sides of the field by prefixing the location with the team's name. In this challenge, you can use a 1 character label or use positive and negative values. It **must** go 0-49,50,49-0 and have a way to differentiate between the sides. Your choice on who owns the 50yd line.

Sample Output: (Our team is A, the opponent's team is B)

```
1st & 7 on A 13
2nd & 10 on A 48
3rd & 12 on 50 OR 3rd & 12 on A 50 OR 3rd & 12 on B 50
4th & 8 on B 10
2nd & Goal on B 7 (read ahead)
```

Your team will start on your own 1 yard line on `1st & 10` (1st down, 10 yards to go for another first down). You will then gain a uniformly random number of yards between `[-3,10]` called `N`. If you didn't get enough for a 1st down, it will now be `2nd & (10 - N)`. Repeat drawing another number between `[-3,10]` and adding the yardage for 2nd and 3rd downs if it's still not enough for a 1st down. If you do gain enough for a 1st down, you simply go back to `1st & 10` on the next go and continue going down the field.

On 4th Down, your team is playing safe and will either punt or go for a Field Goal. If you are further away than their 40, output `P`. If you're within 40 yards, you will attempt a Field Goal with `100 - Yards Away%` chance of success. If you succeed, output `FG`. If you miss, output `NG` ("No Good"). Afterwards, terminate.

However, there are two special situations that must be handled.

If you get within 10yd (inclusive) and gain a 1st Down, It will then be `1st & Goal` and there are no more opportunities to gain 1st downs. Do or die! If you score, output `TD` and terminate, otherwise you'll follow the normal Field goal rules.

If you lose enough yards to go into your own end-zone, that's called a Safety. Simply output a `S` and terminate.

**Rules:**

- No usable input will be provided
- Output is flexible. Tuples and lists of lists are all fine.

**Sample Runs:**
To-Do

**Tags:** Code-golf, random, game

---

Feedback? Does the Field goal add enough meat to be worth including?

Answer (score 0):

## How low can you go?

Time to play so ascii-art limbo!

Here's the bar:

```
|--|
|  |
|  |
```

Can you fit under it?

### Goal

Write a program or function that takes an ascii string representing a some shape, and a positive integer representing a bar height.

Output the shape from the input after it has attempted to do the limbo.

### Details

In limbo you lean back to make yourself as small as possible to fit under the bar, and that is just what the input shapes will try and do.

If the input shape contains any repeating patterns in its lines, then you can remove all but the last of the repetitions that are in the pattern. In additions the pattern must start at the top line, and once the repeating pattern is broken no more sections can be removed.

If there is a repeating pattern that contains another repeating pattern, only the innermost pattern is stripped.

For example this is how the following inputs would look after "Leaning back":

```
1. XXX              2. xxx            3. xxx           4. xxx      
   YYY                 xxx       xxx     xxx              xxx      xxx
   XXX   -->   XXX     yyy  -->  yyy     xxx  -->         yyy      yyy
   YYY         YYY     zzz       zzz     xxx              yyy      yyy
   zzz         zzz     aaa       aaa     xxx      xxx     xxx  --> xxx
                                                          xxx      xxx
                                                          yyy      yyy
                                                          yyy      yyy
```

Note how in example number 4 there was a repetition ox `xxx` insinde of another repetition of `xxx`, `xxx`, `yyy`, `yyy`. In this case only the inner repeating lines got reduced.

The bars will be drawn as shown below for the given heights:

```
1 -> |--|    2 -> |--|   3 -> |--|  etc...
                  |  |        |  |
                              |  |
```

If the given input shape in its reduced form does not fit underneath the bar then the bar will be drawn on the ground like this `|__|`

### Exmaples

Inputs:

```
a. height: 3      b.  height: 2     c.  height: 1
   shape: xxx         shape: xxx        shape: (emptystring)
          xxx                xxx
          xxx                xxx
          yyy                yyy
```

Outputs:

```
a. |--|           b. |  | xxx       c. |--| 
   |  | xxx          |__| yyy  
   |  | yyy
```

### Notes

1. You can assume only valid inputs will be given, handle invalid input however you want
2. The input shape will be drawn 1 space after the bar, and the bottom of the input shape will always line up with the bottom of the bar.
3. Extra whitespace after is fine as long as all the lines are properly aligned.
4. If there is whitespace in the given input then that should be included in the output
5. The shape will not necessarily always line up in a perfect rectangle as I drew it.

This is for code-golf so the answer using the fewest bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

---

Please let me know what you think / if anything is unclear and needs to be improved. Hope you guys like it!

---

EDIT: Would whoever down voted please explain whats wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not the voter, but I'd bet they voted because what you have right now is very difficult to understand. I had to read this three times to figure out what you wanted. It may be worth revisiting the concept of "leaning over" as it is deeply unintuitive to me at the moment. On top of that, this requires a lot of "boring" golfing for the required output format when true/false seems to be basically the same. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hmm, I thought I'd explained it fairly clearly - its just removing any lines that form a repetitive pattern, but I will try to update it. The output is slightly more than just T/F because of wanting to see the "limbo'ed" input shape with the shaved lines, and having to draw the bar different if it fails... though maybe that is what you meant by boring golf?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I tried updating the explanation, though I'm not sure if it is any clearer, please let me know if it makes more sense now

Comment: Explaining things is often harder than one would guess. Here I think a big problem is that your definition of bending is not what I would expect, so it makes the whole idea harder to grasp - particularly the rules about which repetitions happen first. Since I don't get the why I struggle to get the what. Maybe try explaining this to someone verbally to see if you can get rapid and direct feedback. What you have now is better, but I still think I'd have a hard time following on a first read.

Answer (score 0):

## What order(s) can I fire my tonics in?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

---

[Helsing's Fire](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/helsings-fire/id380290526) is a classic mobile game about light. You fire blasts of holy retribution (from chemicals called tonics), using cover to selectively hit enemies in the right sequence.

For this challenge, we're going to ignore the line-of-sight stuff and focus on just the tonic order. Each monster is represented by a string like `RBBGB`—this indicates that, in order to kill it, you need to hit it with a red tonic, followed by 2 blue tonics, then one green tonic and finally one more blue tonic.

Since you're allowed to ignore cover and pick any subset of the monsters to hit, any of the following sequences will kill it:

```
RBBGB
GRBBGBRR
RBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBGGGGBR
RRRBGGGBBRGRBB
```

Your goal is to take in **a list of monsters** as well as **how many of each tonic you have**, and output every possible ordering of tonics that kills every monster, including ones where not every tonic is fired. For instance:

```
R; 2 red -> R, RR
R; 1 red/1 blue -> R, RB, BR
No monsters, but tonics -> every possible permutation of the tonics listed
No tonics, but monsters -> no output, empty set output, or single trailing separator
Neither tonics nor monsters -> empty string
RB,BR; 2 red/2 blue -> RBR, BRB, BRBR, RBBR, RBRB, BRRB
RR,RR,GRG,R,GBR,GR,GRRR,GGR,GB,G,R,BBR; 3 red/2 blue/2 green -> BGRRBGR, BGRRGBR, BGRBRGR, BGRBGRR, BGRGRBR, BGRGBRR, BGBRRGR, BGBRGRR, GRRBBGR, GRRBGBR, GRRGBBR, GRBRBGR, GRBRGBR, GRBBRGR, GRBBGRR, GRBGRBR, GRBGBRR, GRGRBBR, GRGBRBR, GRGBBRR, GBRRBGR, GBRRGBR, GBRBRGR, GBRBGRR, GBRGRBR, GBRGBRR, GBBRRGR, GBBRGRR
BR,R,BR,RBBR,RBR,RGB,RGBR,GB,RGR,GG,GRB,G; 3 red/2 blue/2 green -> RBGRBRG, RBGRBGR, RBGRGBR, RBGGRBR, RGRBBRG, RGRBBGR, RGRBGBR, RGRGBBR, RGBRBRG, RGBRBGR, RGBRGBR, RGBGRBR, RGGRBBR, RGGBRBR, GRRBGBR, GRRGBBR, GRBRGBR, GRBGRBR, GRBGBR, GRBGBRR, GRGRBBR, GRGBRBR, GRGBBR, GRGBBRR
```

---

Would there be a duplicate for this?

Answer (score 0):

## Fun with Lasers and Prisms (WIP)

Given a rectangular grid of objects, one or more laser pointers, and a target, determine if any laser beam will hit the target.

## Objects

ASCII will be used for illustration purposes

- Laser Pointer: `^`, `V`, `<`, `>` - a beam will shoot up, down, left, right, respectively, starting from this cell.
- Target: `O` - return true if a beam reaches this cell
- Mirror: `/`, `\` - reflects a beam 90 degrees
- Prism: `#` - the laser will split into three beams, one for each direction
- One-way block: `A`, `U`, `(`, `)` - a beam will pass up, down, left, right, respectively, but not other directions
- Corridor block: `=`, `"` - a beam will only pass horizontally or vertically, respectively
- Gate block: `I`, `H` - a beam will pass through horizontally if another beam touches it vertically, or vice-versa, respectively

## Rules

- Use any convenient representation

Comment: I think it is likely that your gate blocks prevent this from being a dupe of other similar challenges, though I haven't thoroughly checked yet.

Answer (score 0):

### Auto Tic Tac Toe

Okay, so after thinking about the comment I think I thought of a way to make it more interesting.

---

#### Challenge

Given no input, write a program or function which outputs an entire game of Tic-Tac-Toe where X always wins, or the game ends in a tie.

#### Requirements

- X goes first
- O must make moves at random
- X must make smart moves such that it always wins the game, or the game ends in a tie

#### Example

Here's what I would expect a game to look like:

```
X--
---
---

XO-
---
---

XO-
-X-
---

XOO
-X-
---

XOO
-X-
--X
```

#### Notes:

- X does not need to win in the fewest moves, it is enough to just make it always block O from winning
- You can output the game in whatever form you like, as long as it is easily conveys every turn of the game. For example you could output a string like above, or a list of lists of ints like below, where 0 is an empty space and 1, 2 are X, O respectively:

```
[
  [1,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0], 
  [1,2,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0], 
  [1,2,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0],
  [1,2,2, 0,1,0, 0,0,0], 
  [1,2,2, 0,1,0, 0,0,1]
]
```

This is code golf, answer in the fewest bytes wins. Standard rules apply.

---

Is this a better challenge? I'd love to know what people think

---

Working example of ungolfed code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVVda9swFH33r7grW7FokjpuN9YyB7bRjsIggw5WWPvgxUoj5kiuLCcrxb8904ctyx/dSus8JPE90rn33KOr30ykhO52m5jDLxbzBCJISS7mSz8YdT7IUyhRcCpBU89bFhRusfhBKMXcz0Us8Cl8lYs/XFAxkxi9IToF@RcePJDPknHwCRAKARRUkBSOUBVSD1mC2ecnuYEoguo3HMD0Bvb32/9b8dCN38CrCAJ3Y/VwrFOvMTZWPoH@qEN/1Im/eyl9CV47g8BhOHZ2P3bev3feB33WFmNgGMsOTfgEGre48D80YU3jOaHAK41bsjS@v/LrxSoLbZHJghXKIkCEYg2kGvLrxCXZxCkIvM4@VR416wT7zNIULwRh1P/IeXyv7OcjZNfZNboi6do6UJvdAqo24DTHDm/fsCfdxtoyms4vmITSArdwzy2hXYZyJoS9BJpzaKFIiRh2sx3YbdoDDIvTd3PrdTlwolTNGcELbOslNMF/5stzwnPxUPW7fQIrfATjKeryvNwGevcnWcE17dyaVmXAMkwvMyZyucjS6aHnG0qTlvTOWbxYXaiKcaLsPYINjGeySn@jC0fNVpM4SXyCKu2eU6fSrtmO5GfrTNzLoKtho0OD5DFN2NpHjbH6gjhSfInX2JdD/VtMuKp5ZEa@lWA2c5TSO12qydDWqkG7ihmgVsJcHTq0XZEUuw5HZkjImeRMD@mlKArK3nRSqpgrS7Yc2Qmkj3nV2bYRhpPQ4pmbz2x3oHZ7Uwlmmmar5jgvUmltrZGb@MilQC2tH790HeqpO1UNS92adUyoNenhIWScUGnQ7YrBllF4GwRwKzuX27ht5STHcl4lsCWpbBgGscJVVnqkg5yAHN8VhEsPs0JkhdBTUaxIDncFzpUb2/Vvdbmq48PHoz9UZXrdaW9FbDK18YpAN8ngJks1UFCr7W5kcBZqjVJaA40OaBCyd03Hjz7XdA9173NzAdrlV7oLY3j9UOdeu1YbsyxHMP8nJFSQ70Seo8cQQVlWaXjlbvcX)

Comment: I suspect this hasn't been asked because the huge majority of the work is spent on IO and not on an interesting problem. If you want to ask a tic-tac-toe challenge, you might be better served asking something like "can the next move win" which might still be a lot of parsing, but prevents excessive output at least. That said, you did do a good job of alleviating these problems in your notes, so you may be fine - most of what I've written here is my opinion, not precise advice.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Made a pretty big edit, do you think this would be less boring?

Comment: I think the problem I have with this version is that it is probably more work to make a tic-tac-toe AI than it is to encode all the possible games and just pick one at random to output. It is possible that that isn't true, I haven't tried yet, but it still feels a bit tedious. But this might be the right direction - perhaps instead just ask for one random valid final tic-tac-toe board? Then it will likely be an encoding problem, but perhaps one with interesting strategies. Again, all opinion here, the challenge is written well, etc.

Comment: Do you mean "uniformly distributed" when you write "random"?

Comment: Is the challenge in its current form not a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge with choice?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't think making the AI is actually that hard for tic-tac-toe, though if im underestimating it, i could make a change that `X` always go first, which I think would make the ai pretty trivial

Comment: @JonathanFrech You tell me i have no clue, is that meaning the amount of code to output all possible tictactoe outcomes?

Comment: I am just saying that if you take no input and require a (semi-)static output, a part of the challenge is to find out which tic-tac-toe game requires the least bytes to represent and the rest is a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] task, which in my opinion is s slightly over-used challenge format.

Comment: [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenges are code golf challenges with no input and a static output.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Is that a bad thing then? Do you think this challenge wouldn't  be fun?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman okay fixed my example, hopefully that  illustrates how simple the ai could be

Comment: I feel as though your example does more to demonstrate that nobody would approach this by writing an AI - they would just encode each possible game as Jonathan is suggesting. That doesn't mean it isn't a good challenge, the problem I am trying to get at is that the phrasing of the challenge implies that writing a "player" is required - which I think is a bad requirement. If the challenge was just "output a random, valid, tic-tac-toe board" you could still maybe get an AI solution, if it happened to be shorter, but wouldn't come with a lot of needless baggage. Sorry if this sounds a bit rambly.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman well my example has tons of unnecessary baggage and is not  doing anything in an efficient way in terms of golfing, i just wanted the general algorithm to be shown, id imagine it could easily be shortened to a couple hundred bytes in most languages. That said if they can find a way to output winning board states so long as they show each turn that was played than that would be valid, I don't intend to require anyone to write an AI, just achieve the desired output. Not sure how to rephrase the question to make sure its clear that that is a valid answer.

Comment: @Quinn However, finding such a game would not be done in the submission but to be able to write the submission, leaving the actual challenge itself to be a bit of a boilerplate.

Comment: I guess I've posted one, exactly same but ask for O's input

Answer (score 0):

## Factorise a floating point number

Given a target floating point number, \$T\$ and a set of \$N\$ floating point numbers \$\{x_{1},..,x_{N}\}\$ and a permissible error \$tol\$ , find a set of integer coefficients \$A\$, \$\{m_{1},..,m_{N}\}\$ such that:
$$
A\prod\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^{m_{i}} = T\pm{}tol
$$

### Input

Input will be a target number, a set of real numbers and a tolerance as a decimal or percentage (note which) in any order or format required by your language.

### Output

Output should be \$A\$, \$\{m\}\$ and the corresponding error as a percentage. If multiple combinations are valid any or all sets of \$A\$ and \$\{m\}\$ are within tolerance.

### General rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Examples

\$3*(3.2^4*7.1^2)=15857.614848\$

```
15857.6 [3.2, 7.1] 0.05 => 3, [4, 2]
```

\$2*(e^2*\pi{}^2)=145.854121188\$

```
145.85 [2.7182, 3.1415] 0.1 => 2, [2, 2]
```

\$3*(\pi^0*0.1^1)\$

```
0.3 [3.14159, 0.1] 0.05 => 3, [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Count switches in a smallest square root sequence mod \$2^n\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199208/count-switches-in-a-smallest-square-root-sequence-mod-2n) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Answer (score 0):

## The periodic table and the chemical symbols [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

## Periodic table

The periodic table is a large table<sup>[citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)</sup> where we can find the chemical elements written out with their chemical symbols. For example, Helium shows up as `He` and Carbon shows up as `C`. You can [read Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) on the periodic table, if you want.

## Your task

You have to write a function/program/procedure/... that, given a chemical element's name, returns its chemical symbol. For the purposes of this challenge, we will use the 118 elements listed below:

```
['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron', 'Carbon', 'Nitrogen', 'Oxygen', 'Fluorine', 'Neon', 'Sodium', 'Magnesium', 'Aluminium', 'Silicon', 'Phosphorus', 'Sulfur', 'Chlorine', 'Argon', 'Potassium', 'Calcium', 'Scandium', 'Titanium', 'Vanadium', 'Chromium', 'Manganese', 'Iron', 'Cobalt', 'Nickel', 'Copper', 'Zinc', 'Gallium', 'Germanium', 'Arsenic', 'Selenium', 'Bromine', 'Krypton', 'Rubidium', 'Strontium', 'Yttrium', 'Zirconium', 'Niobium', 'Molybdenum', 'Technetium', 'Ruthenium', 'Rhodium', 'Palladium', 'Silver', 'Cadmium', 'Indium', 'Tin', 'Antimony', 'Tellurium', 'Iodine', 'Xenon', 'Cesium', 'Barium', 'Lanthanum', 'Cerium', 'Praseodymium', 'Neodymium', 'Promethium', 'Samarium', 'Europium', 'Gadolinium', 'Terbium', 'Dysprosium', 'Holmium', 'Erbium', 'Thulium', 'Ytterbium', 'Lutetium', 'Hafnium', 'Tantalum', 'Tungsten', 'Rhenium', 'Osmium', 'Iridium', 'Platinum', 'Gold', 'Mercury', 'Thallium', 'Lead', 'Bismuth', 'Polonium', 'Astatine', 'Radon', 'Francium', 'Radium', 'Actinium', 'Thorium', 'Protactinium', 'Uranium', 'Neptunium', 'Plutonium', 'Americium', 'Curium', 'Berkelium', 'Californium', 'Einsteinium', 'Fermium', 'Mendelevium', 'Nobelium', 'Lawrencium', 'Rutherfordium', 'Dubnium', 'Seaborgium', 'Bohrium', 'Hassium', 'Meitnerium', 'Darmstadtium', 'Roentgenium', 'Copernicium', 'Nihonium', 'Flerovium', 'Moscovium', 'Livermorium', 'Tennessine', 'Oganesson']
```

with the respective element symbols:

```
['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F', 'Ne', 'Na', 'Mg', 'Al', 'Si', 'P', 'S', 'Cl', 'Ar', 'K', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti', 'V', 'Cr', 'Mn', 'Fe', 'Co', 'Ni', 'Cu', 'Zn', 'Ga', 'Ge', 'As', 'Se', 'Br', 'Kr', 'Rb', 'Sr', 'Y', 'Zr', 'Nb', 'Mo', 'Tc', 'Ru', 'Rh', 'Pd', 'Ag', 'Cd', 'In', 'Sn', 'Sb', 'Te', 'I', 'Xe', 'Cs', 'Ba', 'La', 'Ce', 'Pr', 'Nd', 'Pm', 'Sm', 'Eu', 'Gd', 'Tb', 'Dy', 'Ho', 'Er', 'Tm', 'Yb', 'Lu', 'Hf', 'Ta', 'W', 'Re', 'Os', 'Ir', 'Pt', 'Au', 'Hg', 'Tl', 'Pb', 'Bi', 'Po', 'At', 'Rn', 'Fr', 'Ra', 'Ac', 'Th', 'Pa', 'U', 'Np', 'Pu', 'Am', 'Cm', 'Bk', 'Cf', 'Es', 'Fm', 'Md', 'No', 'Lr', 'Rf', 'Db', 'Sg', 'Bh', 'Hs', 'Mt', 'Ds', 'Rg', 'Cn', 'Nh', 'Fl', 'Mc', 'Lv', 'Ts', 'Og']
```

## Input

The code you write should receive an element name in any sensible format, such as a string `"helium"`. You may assume whatever capitalization that suits your needs.

## Output

The code you write should return the element's symbol as a string, with any capitalization that suits your needs. [Bonus imaginary internet points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199102/75323) if you return the symbol with the standard capitalization.

## Scoring

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) so your answer doesn't win by being the shortest! You will be provided `118` test cases. Your score will be your code's byte count divided by the percentage of test cases your code passes correctly. Lowest score wins!

E.g. my code has 1 byte and I get 1 test case correct. My score is \$1 / \frac{1}{118} = 118 \$. Someone else writes some code with 110 bytes but gets all the test cases correct. The other person scores \$ 110 / \frac{118}{118} = 110 \$, meaning the other person has a better score than me.

## Test cases:

```
'Hydrogen' -> 'H'
'Helium' -> 'He'
'Lithium' -> 'Li'
'Beryllium' -> 'Be'
'Boron' -> 'B'
'Carbon' -> 'C'
'Nitrogen' -> 'N'
'Oxygen' -> 'O'
'Fluorine' -> 'F'
'Neon' -> 'Ne'
'Sodium' -> 'Na'
'Magnesium' -> 'Mg'
'Aluminium' -> 'Al'
'Silicon' -> 'Si'
'Phosphorus' -> 'P'
'Sulfur' -> 'S'
'Chlorine' -> 'Cl'
'Argon' -> 'Ar'
'Potassium' -> 'K'
'Calcium' -> 'Ca'
'Scandium' -> 'Sc'
'Titanium' -> 'Ti'
'Vanadium' -> 'V'
'Chromium' -> 'Cr'
'Manganese' -> 'Mn'
'Iron' -> 'Fe'
'Cobalt' -> 'Co'
'Nickel' -> 'Ni'
'Copper' -> 'Cu'
'Zinc' -> 'Zn'
'Gallium' -> 'Ga'
'Germanium' -> 'Ge'
'Arsenic' -> 'As'
'Selenium' -> 'Se'
'Bromine' -> 'Br'
'Krypton' -> 'Kr'
'Rubidium' -> 'Rb'
'Strontium' -> 'Sr'
'Yttrium' -> 'Y'
'Zirconium' -> 'Zr'
'Niobium' -> 'Nb'
'Molybdenum' -> 'Mo'
'Technetium' -> 'Tc'
'Ruthenium' -> 'Ru'
'Rhodium' -> 'Rh'
'Palladium' -> 'Pd'
'Silver' -> 'Ag'
'Cadmium' -> 'Cd'
'Indium' -> 'In'
'Tin' -> 'Sn'
'Antimony' -> 'Sb'
'Tellurium' -> 'Te'
'Iodine' -> 'I'
'Xenon' -> 'Xe'
'Cesium' -> 'Cs'
'Barium' -> 'Ba'
'Lanthanum' -> 'La'
'Cerium' -> 'Ce'
'Praseodymium' -> 'Pr'
'Neodymium' -> 'Nd'
'Promethium' -> 'Pm'
'Samarium' -> 'Sm'
'Europium' -> 'Eu'
'Gadolinium' -> 'Gd'
'Terbium' -> 'Tb'
'Dysprosium' -> 'Dy'
'Holmium' -> 'Ho'
'Erbium' -> 'Er'
'Thulium' -> 'Tm'
'Ytterbium' -> 'Yb'
'Lutetium' -> 'Lu'
'Hafnium' -> 'Hf'
'Tantalum' -> 'Ta'
'Tungsten' -> 'W'
'Rhenium' -> 'Re'
'Osmium' -> 'Os'
'Iridium' -> 'Ir'
'Platinum' -> 'Pt'
'Gold' -> 'Au'
'Mercury' -> 'Hg'
'Thallium' -> 'Tl'
'Lead' -> 'Pb'
'Bismuth' -> 'Bi'
'Polonium' -> 'Po'
'Astatine' -> 'At'
'Radon' -> 'Rn'
'Francium' -> 'Fr'
'Radium' -> 'Ra'
'Actinium' -> 'Ac'
'Thorium' -> 'Th'
'Protactinium' -> 'Pa'
'Uranium' -> 'U'
'Neptunium' -> 'Np'
'Plutonium' -> 'Pu'
'Americium' -> 'Am'
'Curium' -> 'Cm'
'Berkelium' -> 'Bk'
'Californium' -> 'Cf'
'Einsteinium' -> 'Es'
'Fermium' -> 'Fm'
'Mendelevium' -> 'Md'
'Nobelium' -> 'No'
'Lawrencium' -> 'Lr'
'Rutherfordium' -> 'Rf'
'Dubnium' -> 'Db'
'Seaborgium' -> 'Sg'
'Bohrium' -> 'Bh'
'Hassium' -> 'Hs'
'Meitnerium' -> 'Mt'
'Darmstadtium' -> 'Ds'
'Roentgenium' -> 'Rg'
'Copernicium' -> 'Cn'
'Nihonium' -> 'Nh'
'Flerovium' -> 'Fl'
'Moscovium' -> 'Mc'
'Livermorium' -> 'Lv'
'Tennessine' -> 'Ts'
'Oganesson' -> 'Og'
```

I used [this code](https://tio.run/##dVbbjts2EH33VwjOQ2xgE6ToW4AWkOXbYn2D5aTZbYuCkmiLXYoUeNlUKPrt2xlSIhW08ZNmODM8c@ZCt52ppfjx9VUnPyXT6XSSwG@bvEu2XaXkjQqvoKihnNnGyTsG8o6ZelAs0GBBVceDzQI1UkkfIQMpI6roxQOIB2biDUdQHP/qBnEN4ppbqZig3gEvONDBnYCUy2q4a38DeU9ugupBlXJQpdw2TNjmrv8aDnPEnzPOyj7gCeRTLXVbS2W1t0ETy69W@QQwXlbzCClVeIO69SEeMIQ0RAcIGXFJ8zJcW2LMkogA/IJALsyQAO0zKD4TQYJJptzFSjYhW@GyFTcC@Xosa6TnPpAt0UUWhBtPF3N0l8@U@3PrztuW@tyeMOATE6WTNgh7Q2IlNxh8Q1UTUaba5a6pYN4pR5ucchpMFoh7gbB7vh5Q8aC61vQwzwUozrZgIdccTXJoC2EG1SNoHo1Rg/ykHFYFlRtUh8KlJ4tAEOa/l7wrKioGppH7Cy1rQUPss3UATB1Rn2tU1bG1ThXWFdiIFUlvvnteevqyytW5CgW6Rz7vY5Vz4arss84RbQoJNlJ0Hhp10Di3Ict7DAAgeuq@oMUXKob6IvtZ7PUFVmxBgvcO5R0RpiZD@hl1LsHkhDSeFNFUVl0Afqj8lI1Up8YZyobGac9Rl5Mm3rhCJldWyTY0TeW6qJI8jt2lcImqUKhlB4plp1slQzJbLN5W8oBghVBX0emCt19qG/rzsfA9Mgq8Qzw7a2Ktt1cMS64RDJJ0AZII7zW/oMKKmzb9FjpT1wyxO45I/FHHQis3drGBTwbZ4sSwgfgUkWwkrzwKt6ioKq3qa89dMqNpO2E2O0q8wwJHd8F0A13qj6XbMzy2f4p3ptrgpb5dzthvZ@C@X6aIcq2ICIvoTLxBCIHDkZZmVKra4ZKxYYjvA0PGZp9A@UnFvXBoXQO1xgbVyTpKrBkhxgqmDXRjQJShKosDsHj2D8pzfHSyq1@n7CpVCLXCiqyYgJpFVGsMtoaFFRZC5WgXFSyol4AVmTzIYvSsKTc3XxUdUXUddoSCewNjS6zS0hbxSXFLgZJCqltIonZvYB2y2mrXhPGJ2BsHjBkRR3OJRkuiGihpFXcVxj9LKswt9mMm/CKnQEhAfKjdOqwj32vunlOqZEh@X7oVqcuo2r24Rx22WhPLftFuZAW8NHporyNCObrXR0OL4b@GCYe/D5xpM2tIO@OkKSqS6I@Jfq9hdbez@R1@tpyZ2fQ3MZ3P59HjyjiM7tjpLuFjg/@E9HEAxHTuTSdvkq@KGZrAjtKJtGaiu6aQXP9PCPMxMb9@@N07vmnhOTez3no@gf5ogOLv@v3wrd9gPp8Yqs0fJazT77hep2//Rvd/3ibvfk7w@wN8T7@JFmNARl6FZL3/UzIxPpy/vv4L) to shape the list into the test cases, might be useful to you.

Elements and symbols extracted from https://www.thoughtco.com/element-list-names-atomic-numbers-606529, visited at the 9th of February of 2020. At the time of writing, 118 elements were available. Source included "Aluminum" and "Aluminium" as alternatives, dropped "Aluminum" for the purposes of this challenge.

Comment: This is just a massive lookup table. I don't like it.

Comment: "Aluminum" might be in the dictionaries of some languages. I suggest allowing either but and/or both in the solution and specifying which one was chosen.

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38592/76162)

Comment: @JoKing this being a code challenge doesn't make it different from the dupe you linked?

Comment: I think the problem you have is that your scoring strongly incentivises submitting `H` as the best answer. The other question had a shortest solution of 200 bytes - which can't get a better score than the 1 byte 1 answer program.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks for the feedback. Would you suggest tweaking the score or dropping this challenge?

Comment: You might consider a similar idea but with something that hasn't been done as much. I think it depends on how you feel, it certainly isn't unsalvageable.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman very nice idea. I am thinking airport codes, country codes or military rank abbreviations...

Comment: I really like this idea, and I think allowing approximate answers makes it distinct enough from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38592/76162) that it's not a dupe.
However, the current scoring encourages *very* inaccurate, trivial answers. The best I could find in 05AB1E is `2£` (05AB1E to output the first 2 characters of the input),
which gets 45 test cases correct, scoring better than a 6 character answer that gets everything right.

Comment: @Grimmy thanks for your very detailed feedback! Like I mentioned above, I'm exploring the possibility of using something other than chemical symbols. In your opinion, would you tweak the scoring or would you suggest something other than chemical symbols?

Answer (score 0):

## Compress even permutations

### Factorial number system

Every nonnegative integer can be encoded by **factorial number system**. Factorial number system doesn't have a fixed radix, but uses the factorial of nonnegative integers as radices. The place of \$0!\$ can have \$0\$ as the digit, the place of \$1!\$ can have \$0\$ or \$1\$ as the digit, the place of \$2!\$ can have \$0\$, \$1\$, or \$2\$ as the digit, and so on. Subscript exclamation mark denotes that the integer is encoded in factorial number system. For example:

$$
41010_! = 4 \times 4! + 1 \times 3! + 0 \times 2! + 1 \times 1! + 0 \times 0!= 103_{10}
$$

### Permutations

Numbers encoded by factorial number system has one-to-one correspondence to permutations:

$$
41010_! \cong
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That is, each the place of \$n!\$ represents a right-direction rotation of \$n\$ through \$0\$, and its digit represents what \$0\$ becomes after the rotation.

It follows that the parity of the permutation is same as the parity of the sum of digits at the places of factorials of odd numbers. For \$41010_!\$, the permutation is even because \$1 + 1 = 2\$ is even.

### Objective

An even permutation of 5 elements, or any equivalent object will be the input. That leaves \$5! \div 2 = 60\$ distinct permutations. Compress it to \$\lceil \log_2{60}\rceil=6\$ bits.

### Rules

- Input type and format doesn't matter. Possible choices of input format include (in C++):

  - `std::map<int,int>` scrambling the numbers from \$4\$ to \$0\$
  - `int[5]` containing the digits of the factorial number system
  - `int[4]` containing the digits of the factorial number system, except the place of \$0!\$ (it doesn't contribute to the permutation)
  - `int` encoded by the factorial number system
- Output type and format doesn't matter either. It may be:

  - `bool[6]`
  - `int8_t`
  - a bit field
  - `std::string` containing ASCII digit 0s and 1s
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplify a directed graph

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Input

A connected directed graph, in any convenient format. A valid format (and probably the most convenient) would be a list of edges.

### Simplification

These two reductions are performed as often as possible. It does not suffice to apply one reduction first, then the other, as each of them can cause more of the other one.

Let \$E\$ be the set of all edges of the graph in the following explanations. For example \$E = \{(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)\}\$ represents the following graph:

```
0 ----> 1
^       |
'-- 2 <-'
```

Let \$E_a\$, where \$a\$ is a vertex, indicate the set of edges involving \$a\$:

$$E_a := \{(u, v) \in E : u = a \vee v = a\}$$

Two graphs are isomorphic iff all vertices from one graph can be relabeled to make it equal to the other graph.

#### Deduplication

If there are disjoint sets of vertices \$M\$ and \$N\$ (\$M \cap N = \emptyset\$) not directly connected (\$((M, N) \cup (N, M)) \cap E = \emptyset\$) and the graphs with edges \$E \setminus E_M\$ and \$E \setminus E_N\$ are isomorphic, then the vertices \$M\$ (or \$N\$, but not both, are removed).

This means that of any two non-overlapping, non-directly-connected subgraphs that leave isomorphic graphs behind when removed, one is removed.

```
Simple example:

b --> 1
      ^  ==>  b --> 1
      |
      a
```

#### Relay removal

If there are vertices \$a\$ and \$b\$ and a non-empty set of vertices \$N\$, such that \$b \notin N\$ and \$E_b = \{(a, b)\} \cup (b, N)\$, then \$b\$ is removed from the graph and edges \$(a, N)\$ are added if they do not alreay exist.

This means that a vertex with exactly one edge ending there, at least one edge starting there and no self-loop can be removed, moving the starting edges to the start of the ending edge.

```
Simple example:

            1             1
            ^             ^
            |             |
O --> a --> b  ==>  O --> a ----.
      ^     |             ^     |
      |     v             |     v
      '---- 2             '---- 2
```

### Output

The output is the result of the reductions, in any convenient format. If identifiers are used for edges or vertices, as in a list of edges, these identifiers are not required to correspond to identifiers in the input.

A different format may be used for input and output.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): Lowest bytecount in each language wins. No answer will be accepted, as there is no overall winner.

### Other rules

- Standard loopholes apply
- Functions or programs
- Any input and output methods (STDIN, arguments, `prompt()`, ...)

### Test cases

*not yet*

> ### Meta:
>
> - Everything clear?
> - Better explanations?
> - Better title?
> - I'm not sure whether output might depend on the order in which reductions are performed.

Answer (score 0):

## Shared Letters in consecutive numbers

Inspired by [this puzzling question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93940/letters-in-consecutive-numbers).

It turns out that, in English, every pair of consecutive integers (e.g. `0,1`, `1,2`, etc.) shares at least one letter when spelled out (e.g. `zErO, OnE` (or `NOught, ONe`); `One, twO`, etc).

### Input

Any two non-negative integers (all natural numbers including 0) up to and including one googol. These can be input as any type you choose, but string representations must only use the characters `0123456789.,'` (i.e. the numbers must not already be spelled out on input, but rather input as a numeral).

You can assume that the two numbers will be consecutive.

Some examples of valid inputs:

{1,2}
{"1","2"}
{1},{2}
{{"1"},{2}}
"123,245", "123,246"
"123.456", "123'457"

some examples of **in**valid inputs

{1,3}
{-1,0}
{1.1,1.2}
{"one","two"}

**The Challenge**

Given the two inputs, output all shared characters when spelled (both numbers spelled in either lower or upper-case, the same case for both numbers).

A sample implementation for spelling numbers can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911982/318414; but I'm sure other options exist; and there are certainly efficiencies to be found given that there are large amounts of shared strings, once you get into the higher numbers. See also https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_large_numbers for the names of large numbers.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), usual exclusions apply

**Output**
The shared letters, in any reasonable format. Any of the three numbering systems on the Wikipedia page are valid.

**Examples**

I will be assuming British English (long form) in my examples.

`{6,7}` -> `"s"` or `"S"` (six, seven)

`{999,1000}` -> `{"n","e"," ","t","h","u","a","d"}` (**n**i**ne hund**r**ed and n**i**net**y **n**i**ne**, o**ne th**o**u**s**and**)

`{88955,88956}` -> `` (**eighty eight thousand nine hundred and fifty fi**v**e**, **eighty eight thousand nine hundred and fifty si**x)

`1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` -> `"ONE THUSADQICL"` (**ONE THOUSAND QUINDECILLION**, **ONE THOUSAND QUINDECILLION AND ONE**)

`9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` -> `el no` (**n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d s**e**xd**e**ci**ll**i**on **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d qui**n**d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d quattur**o**d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d tr**e**d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d du**o**d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d u**n**d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d d**e**ci**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d **non**i**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d **o**cti**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d s**e**pti**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d s**e**xti**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d qui**n**ti**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d quadri**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d tri**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d bi**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d mi**ll**i**o**n **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne** th**o**usa**n**d **n**i**ne** hundr**e**d and **n**i**ne**ty **n**i**ne**; **one** g**oo**g**ol**)

Comment: "Any two positive integers (all natural numbers including 0)" You should reword this because 0 is not a positive integer.

Comment: Possibly a chameleon challenge because answerers are required to convert an integer to its English form first, which could take much more effort than finding the shared letters.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto I'm envisaging that the intermediate step won't necessarily need to be performed in code - perhaps there's a way to just look at the numbers? If not, does a challenge exist for converting numbers to words yet?

Answer (score 0):

## Let's Play Countdown!

(The Numbers round this time)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Countdown is a British TV game show composed of three different styles of rounds; [the letters round](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38233/lets-play-countdown), the conundrum, and the numbers round.

The conundrum could be solved with the same program you'd make for the Letters round, so let's tackle the third option that hasn't been done yet!

### Challenge

Take in a set of numbers. One of which is the "Target" number, and the rest are the building numbers.

The Countdown Number Round asks you to take the building numbers and to construct the Target number only using the four elementary operators. Every step must result in another strictly-positive integer (so non-perfect division is disallowed). Output the method to which you can construct the target number. If that's impossible, get as close as possible (above or below are scored the same). Numbers do not need to be used, but may NOT be reused.

Note - You will perform at most N-1 operations, where N is the number of building numbers. Every elementary operator takes in two inputs and provides one, so you "lose" one from your ranking every operation. That should give you an idea of the size of your output.

I/O is in any reasonable format, but target vs building numbers must be obviously distinct (either by the target being the first or the last number, or outside an array, or a different type, etc).

Output needs to explain exactly what operations are being performed on what numbers, and what the output for each operation would be, but can be done in whichever way seems reasonable.

### Example I/O

```
In these examples, the first element is the target.

[888 100 2 75 3 1 10]
75-1=74
10+2=12
74x12=888

[766 22 10 8 3 1]
22+10=32
32x8=256
256-1=255
255x3=765 #You cannot get this one exactly, but one-off is close.
```

### Sandbox Questions

I'm... like 85% sure this isn't anywhere here yet. I did a chunk of searching and couldn't find anything that fit the bill, so I think this is clear?

Any other neat examples you guys got?

Comment: As you say, I don't think we have exactly this challenge, but there are many similar ones. I doubt you will get anything besides brute forcing all possible arrangements then sorting them by nearness to the target. Separately, if there are multiple tying solutions you don't require that e.g. the shortest be output, correct? It is probably worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

**Iterative Quadratics**

Recently, in my algebra class, we proved that the following process always stops at some point, so I thought it would be a cool challenge!

**Input**: Two reals a,b.

**Output** Non-negative integer

**Challenge**:

Given two reals a,b, initialize a count variable c to 0, consider the quadratic equation

```
x^2+ax+b
```

If this quadratic has real roots r,s (r<=s), increment the counter by 1, and replace a,b with r,s and repeat the process.

If the quadratic has complex roots, return c.

**Test Cases**

To be added.

Comment: you need to specify the precision required for stopping

Comment: @qwr good catch. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Doubly stochastic matrix [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A [doubly-stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) is a square matrix of non-negative real entries each of whose rows and columns sums to 1. Given a doubly-stochastic matrix, express it as a non-negative linear combination of [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), as is guaranteed to exist by the [Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem](http://Birkhoff%E2%80%93von%20Neumann%20theorem).

TODO: Example, better explanation, test cases. If you want to develop and post this challenge, it's yours.

Comment: I liked this idea! May I work on this and give you credit? If I manage to do so before you, of course.

Comment: @RGS You're very welcome to fully take it.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement GF(2²)

### Introduction to groups and fields

An **additive group** is a set with **addition** and **negation** defined. They must satisfy the following conditions:

- \$0\$ is the additive identity.
- Addition is associative.
- For every \$x\$, the negation of \$x\$, \$-x\$ exists, and \$x + (-x) = (-x) + x = 0\$.

If addition is also commutative, the additive group is called **abelian**.

A **field** is an additive abelian group with **multiplication** and **reciprocal** defined. They must satisfy the following conditions:

- \$1\$ is the multiplicative identity.
- Multiplication is associative and commutative.
- For every nonzero \$x\$, the reciprocal of \$x\$, \$x^{-1}\$ *uniquely* exists, and \$x\times x^{-1} = x^{-1}\times x = 1\$.
- Multiplication distributes over addition.

### Modular Arithmetic

For every positive integer \$n\$, you can define an additive abelian group as follows:

- Define the set as integers from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$.
- Define addition as usual addition with the result moduloed by \$n\$.
- Define negation as usual negation with the result moduloed by \$n\$.

This group is denoted by \$ℤ_n\$. If \$n\$ is prime, multiplication can be analogously defined, making it a field.  In particular, the operation tables of \$ℤ_2\$ are:

$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
+ & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|ll}
x & -x \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|ll}
× & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|ll}
x & x^{-1} \\ \hline
0 & \text{NaN} \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

### Galois Field GF(2²)

A **Galois field** \$\text{GF}(p^k)\$ emerges when one takes the set as polynomials over \$ℤ_p\$, and defines addition and multiplication as the usual operation with polynomial modulo, where the modding polynomial is **irreducible** and has degree of \$k\$. Since \$x^2+x+1\$ is an (in fact, the only) irreducible polynomial over \$ℤ_2\$ that has degree \$2\$, this results in \$\text{GF}(2^2)\$. Its operation tables are:

$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
+ & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & x+1 & x \\
x & x & x+1 & 0 & 1 \\
x+1 & x+1 & x & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|ll}
f(x) & -f(x) \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
x & x \\
x+1 & x+1
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{l|ll}
× & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\
x & 0 & x & x+1 & 1 \\
x+1 & 0 & x+1 & 1 & x
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|ll}
f(x) & f(x)^{-1} \\ \hline
0 & \text{NaN} \\
1 & 1 \\
x & x+1 \\
x+1 & x
\end{array}
$$

Your task is to implement the set and the operations. As a conseuqence, you must have:

- The members of the set defined as constants (2-bit bitstring, an ASCII digit, or whatever). This won't contribute to the score.
- Four codes that defines each operations, whose input(s) is/are as defined above.

### Rules

- Though defined as polynomials, the type and format of the inputs doesn't matter. You must have the same type for every input.
- The type and format of the outputs doesn't matter either, but it must be the same as the input(s).
- The reciprocal of \$0\$ must result in an "error" condition. This includes returning an errornous value, throwing an error, or terminating the program. It must halt.
- Other invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.
- Since there are multiple codes, the score for code golf is alloted by the sum of their lengths in bytes.

Comment: Related: [GF(2^8)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82867/78410) and [GF(3^2)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197320/78410), though neither asks for negation or multiplicative inverse. Also, `A code that defines the set as a type` can be problematic in many languages where the concept of "type" is not well-defined. I'd suggest to exclude it from the code size and just ask the answerer to provide the four values corresponding to \$0, 1, x, x+1\$ respectively.

Comment: @DonThousand Requiring the uniqueness of a negation resolves the issue. Also, it would take too long to explain the "actual" definition of \$\mathbb{Z}_p\$. So I defined it with *usual* modulo.

Comment: @DonThousand \$(-a) + a = 0\$ implies \$(-(-a)) + (-a) = 0\$. So both \$a\$ and \$-(-a)\$ are additive inverses of \$-a\$. By uniqueness of additive inverse, it follows \$-(-a) = a\$.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Incorrect, you assume commutativity again. $a$ is a right inverse, and $-(-a)$ is a left inverse of $-a$

Comment: @DonThousand The definition of group states that a left inverse *must be* the right inverse, and a right inverse *must be* the left inverse. Such inverse always uniquely exists.

Comment: @DannyuNDos That's my point. Your definition doesn't say that the right inverse = left inverse.

Comment: @DonThousand Oh my! So there was the flaw. I only *remembered* the definition, but not *memorized* it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Yea, lol. Sheesh, that was a journey.

Comment: @DonThousand You only need a right zero and right inverses, then we get left zero and left inverses, and they are unique (we also don't have to demand that). Proof that right inverses are left inverses: \$(-a)+a=(-a)+a+0=(-a)+a+(((-a)+a)+(-((-a)+a)))=(-a)+(a+(-a))+a+(-((-a)+a))=((-a)+0)+a+(-((-a)+a))=((-a)+a)+(-((-a)+a))=0\$. Using this gives left zero: \$0+a=(a+(-a))+a=a+((-a)+a)=a+0=a\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Find spies in a multilingual csv

## Introduction

You are an NSA undercover agent in a Middle-Eastern HR company, you just received a list of people with their jobs in many different languages. Some are spies and you need to know who. Your mission, if you accept it, is to get what are people working in, and relate it to a list of job categories. Most dangerous elements are those working in `Law enforcement and security`. However as your code will be part of a bigger file it needs to be as short in lines as possible for stealthness.
This comes from expectations I encountered in the administration to keep some mystery behind code, if ever it were to be stolen.

- This challenges your way to handle loops, map, reduce and filter, destructuring or unpacking an array/csv/df. Last but not least it allows you to get into the fascinating world of cross-language nlp.

I provide an example in python (64 lines of code)

## Challenge

The challenge is to get, in the shortest amount of bytes (libraries not included) the most similar element in an array of string with another string, and this for each line of a csv taken as input.

- Inputs:

  1. `X.csv` a csv/dataframe of actual jobs that look like this one:

```
,new_professionactuelle
0,Entrepreneur
1,طالبة
2,ETUDIANT
3,ETUDIANT 
4,موظف
5,موجه تربوي 
6,Réalisateur film cartoon
7,إإطار مالي
8,موضف إطار
9,مهندس بمكتب دراسات
10,باحثة  _ كاتبة _ 
11,طالب
12,Chef de projet
13,ASSUREUR
14,FONCTIONNAIRE D'ÉTAT
15,Professeur Universitaire
16,cadre supérieur
17,fonctionnaire
19,professeur
20,Chef de projet
21,مدير  شركة
22,Avocat
23,cadre à Maroc Telecom
24,Employé 
25,Consultant en Immobilier
26,fonctionnaire
27,اجير أو عامل
```

2. `df.csv` job categories that must include all the following categories:

   ```
   ['Agriculture, farming and environment',
      'Accountancy, banking and finance',
      'Teacher training and education', 'Leisure, sport and tourism',
      'Transport and logistics', 'Information technology',
      'Hospitality and events management',
      'Business, consulting and management', 'Creative arts and design',
      'Trade', 'Law enforcement and security',
      'Property and construction', 'Law',
      'Engineering and manufacturing', 'Social care',
      'Charity and voluntary work', 'Sales',
      'Public services and administration', 'Other. Please specify:',
      'Healthcare', 'Energy and utilities',
      'Marketing, advertising and PR', 'Media and internet',
      'Recruitment and HR', 'Science and pharmaceuticals']
   ```

   - Output would be the column in `X.csv`  plus a new column, the most similar job. The most accurate results are:

```
,new_professionactuelle,category
0,Entrepreneur,Public services and administration
1,طالبة,Teacher training and education
2,ETUDIANT,Teacher training and education
3,ETUDIANT ,Teacher training and education
4,موظف,Recruitment and HR
5,موجه تربوي ,Teacher training and education
6,Réalisateur film cartoon,Creative arts and design
7,إإطار مالي,"Accountancy, banking and finance"
8,موضف إطار,Trade
9,مهندس بمكتب دراسات,Engineering and manufacturing
10,باحثة  _ كاتبة _ ,Recruitment and HR
11,طالب,Teacher training and education
12,Chef de projet,Creative arts and design
13,ASSUREUR,Business, consulting and management
14,FONCTIONNAIRE D'ÉTAT,Public services and administration
15,Professeur Universitaire,Teacher training and education
16,cadre supérieur,Business, consulting and management
17,fonctionnaire,Public services and administration
18,CDB Retraite,Recruitment and HR
19,professeur,Teacher training and education
20,Chef de projet,Public services and administration
21,مدير  شركة,Recruitment and HR
22,Avocat,Law
23,cadre à Maroc Telecom,Media and internet
24,Employé ,Sales
25,Consultant en Immobilier,Property and construction
26,fonctionnaire,Public services and administration
27,اجير أو عامل,Recruitment and HR
```

- Inputs should be tested against all categories.

The winner of the challenge will be the one with the most accurate results. If on the test set. If several are as accurate, the shortest amount of bytes will be the winner. You can use any methods to get the most similar item. The state of the art method seems to be according to [Google Multilingual Universal Sentence encoder](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/cross_lingual_similarity_with_tf_hub_multilingual_universal_encoder.ipynb#scrollTo=Q8F4LNGFqOiq). I provide an attempt with the code below but you will see it is not quite acccurate.

## Example in Python

> *Double agent: A spy who works for two countries, and sometimes even three, in which case he is definitely a trouble.* - Mots et Grumots (2003), Marc Escayrol

```
#@title Setup common imports and functions
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
import sklearn.metrics.pairwise

from simpleneighbors import SimpleNeighbors
from tqdm import tqdm
from tqdm import trange

import json

def most_similar(embeddings_1, embeddings_2, labels_1, labels_2):

  assert (len(embeddings_1) == len(labels_1) and len(embeddings_2) == len(labels_2))

  # arccos based text similarity (Yang et al. 2019; Cer et al. 2019)
  sim = 1 - np.arccos(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(embeddings_1, embeddings_2))/np.pi

  embeddings_1_col, embeddings_2_col, sim_col = [], [], []
  for i in range(len(embeddings_1)):
    for j in range(len(embeddings_2)):
      embeddings_1_col.append(labels_1[i])
      embeddings_2_col.append(labels_2[j])
      sim_col.append(sim[i][j])
  df = pd.DataFrame(zip(embeddings_1_col, embeddings_2_col, sim_col),
                    columns=['embeddings_1', 'embeddings_2', 'sim'])

  # return the higest similarity one
  category = df['embeddings_1'].iloc[df['sim'].argmax()]
  return category

def main():

    X = pd.read_csv('X.csv')
    y = pd.read_csv('y.csv')
    df_rni = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

    # The 16-language multilingual module is the default but feel free
    # to pick others from the list and compare the results.
    module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3' #@param ['https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3', 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3']

    model = hub.load(module_url)

    def embed_text(input):
        return model(input)

    def compute_similarity(references, target):
        # I want to create as many rows as there are references and fill them with the results
        # arccos based text similarity (Yang et al. 2019; Cer et al. 2019)
        for row in target.iterrows():
            for reference in references:
                sim = 1 - np.arccos(
                result = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(row,
                                                                    reference))/np.pi

            # place the result in the column "reference"

    # get unique job categories and job of people
    job_categories = X.S02Q11_Professional_field.unique()
    # turn them to list
    job_categories = job_categories.tolist()
    # emebedding job categories 
    references_result = embed_text(job_categories[1:])

    for _, row in df_rni.iterrows():
        actual_job = row['new_professionactuelle']
        # check for nan that can't be embedded
        if str(actual_job) != 'nan':
            # embedding actual job
            target_result = embed_text(actual_job)
            # visualize similarity
            category = most_similar(references_result, target_result, job_categories[1:], [actual_job])
        else: category = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Arnauld Indeed, fixed, thanks!

Comment: It looks like your reference code fetches output from an external source, which is [forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/6484). Please detail within the question how one would implement the Google Universal Sentence Encoder. (If the challenge actually requires querying https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3, I don't think that's gonna be appropriate for CGCC).

Comment: @Grimmy Google Universal Encoder: that's not compulsory, but I find it very handy and a good tip to start. External source: yes, that's the way I provided example data like the inputs above. Should I hard code the sources?

Comment: Wait, Google Universal Encoder isn't compulsory? That seems to contradict `the most similar element in an array of string with another string according to Google Multilingual Universal Sentence encoder`. If GMUSE isn't required, this sentence should be replaced by a proper definition of "most similar element", and GMUSE should only be mentioned in the footnotes.

Comment: `External source: yes, that's the way I provided example data like the inputs above`. I'm confused. Do you use https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3 only to get example data? It sure doesn't look like that in your code.

Comment: @Grimmy Porbably I misunderstood _"It looks like your reference code fetches output from an external source"_ then, my apologizes.

Comment: This needs an explanation of how "accuracy" is computed. (And you still need to define "most similar").

Answer (score 0):

## [Shift the letters, soldier !](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205564/shift-the-letters-soldier)

*posted, finally*

Comment: Thank you for sandboxing this. I usually recommend doing so for at least a week, and periodically ask for review in TNB.

Comment: I think people would be forced to do the bonus in this case because of the -30% margin. I got a 42 without bonus but a 57*0.7=39.9 with bonus in JS.

Comment: Bonuses are [discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/31625) for a variety of reasons. I would strongly recommend either making it mandatory or completely leaving it out.

Comment: The main challenge is add by position, the bonus challenge is minus by position. So it's a good idea to completely leave the bonus out.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll remove the bonus as it will never be balanced enouth to be interesting. I'll add some example as soon as I can.

Comment: I would say that allowing the usage of the ascii range 1 to 255 or a language's code page could allow for some interesting golfs :)

Comment: Use asciii values from 0 to 255 was my original plan, but I'm afraid some interestings languages would be disadvantaged. Also, wouldn't the usage of language's code page be too permissive ?

Comment: @Therandomguy it depends on what you mean by "too permissive". Sometimes it is done, as it may allow some languages to do some funny things. As to the range being from 0 to 255, I don't see it hurting any language at all, but of course I may be missing something :)

Comment: Are you interested in re-posting it?

Comment: This weekend I'll post it, I just need some time creating the examples

Comment: I'd be glad to see it posted in Main!

Comment: Finally posted it in main

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the Pareto frontier

Given a set of triplets, output its [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier).

### Definitions

A triplet is a list of 3 positive integers, for example `[120, 15, 21]` (order matters).

A triplet `[A, B, C]` is objectively worse than `[a, b, c]` when `A >= a`, `B >= b`, and `C >= c` (lower is better).

A triplet is on the Pareto frontier when it's not objectively worse than any other triplet in the input.

### I/O rules

Input and output are both a set of triplets. Each triplet must be represented
as either a list of integers (`[1, 2, 3]`) or a `/`-delimited string (`"1/2/3"`).
The format of the outer sets is flexible (built-in set type, list, or delimited
string are all okay).

### Test cases

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]] => [[1, 1, 1]]
[[3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2]] => [[3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2]]
... (more to come) ...
```

Comment: I had sandboxed a [similar challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9575/20260), but it didn't seem to be going anywhere and I wasn't going to post it. Maybe the discussion on it about filtering is somewhat relevant to this.

Comment: The IO rule for the triplets seems odd, why not any kind of ordered list?

Answer (score 0):

A similar challenge was posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/convert-from-infix-notation-to-prefix-notation) but that's outdated and I have a few twists.

### Challenge

Write a program, expression or subroutine which, given an arithmetical expression in infix notation, like `1 + 2`, outputs the same expression in postfix notation except the numbers are now float representative in the string, i.e. `1.0 2.0 +`.

The input can include parentheses (()), exponents (^), division (/) and multiplication (*), addition (+) and subtraction (-) (in that order of operation), such as

`4 ^ (2 / 3) * 9 * 3 - - 4 * 6`

output the same expression in prefix notation.

`4.0 2.0 3.0 / ^ 9.0 * 3.0 * -4.0 6.0 * -`

Spaces are optional in the input as well as the output.

### Twists

- Must support using floats too, instead of just integers. so `4 ^ (2.0/3.0) * 9.0 * 3.0 - - 4 *6` output's is the same as the ones above.
- Must return a string with all numbers as its float representative instead of as its original form, so 9 -> 9.0 and if it was 9.0 it stays 9.0.
- Must support negation (see example above "3.0 - - 4" ends up with "-4.0", negative sign stays in place).
- Cannot use exec() or eval() functions.

### Assumptions

- You can assume that there will not be any special numbers such as those in scientific notation or those with hanging zeroes, e.g. 000004 or 0005.000000.
- You should also not assume the commutative or associative properties. This means that, while the operators will move around, the numbers will always remain in the same order.
- You can always assume a valid infix input.

### Clarifications

- You should not evaluate any expression.
- The output should not contain any unneeded parentheses. ((2+1))-1 should reduce to 2+1-1.

### Game Winning Criteria

**Fewest amount of characters wins.** Bytes are not of a matter here.

Comment: To reiterate my comment on the original question: 1. [Using the word "twist" is not recommended.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16186/78410) 2. [Don't ban `exec/eval` just because you don't like it.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/78410) The task isn't about evaluating the value, so it is unnecessary and pretty much arbitrary. 3. You say "prefix notation", but `4.0 2.0 3.0 / ^ 9.0 * 3.0 * -4.0 6.0 * -` is in postfix, not prefix. You should fix either the description or the example result.

Comment: And you didn't explain why you want to handle unary negation in a different way (which is essentially changing the underlying expression, which seems against "You should not evaluate any expression"). By using a different symbol for unary minus (say `~`), it is possible to translate the example to postfix as `4.0 2.0 3.0 / ^ 9.0 * 3.0 * 4.0 ~ 6.0 * -`.

Comment: For [tag:code-golf] scoring, [scoring by bytes is preferred over characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2364/78410). (I believe there must be a more persuasive argument somewhere...)

Comment: The second line in "clarifications" is unnecessary because "postfix notation" implies no parentheses. For the floating-point output, do you have a reason to demand adding `.0` to integer values? A floating-point number `4` can be printed as `4`, `4.`, or `4.0`, and all of them represent the same value anyway.

Comment: The linked challenge explicitly assumes left-associativity for all operators `^ * / + -` (that is, `1 - 2 + 3 = (1 - 2) + 3`, `4 / 5 * 6 = (4 / 5) * 6`, and `7 ^ 8 ^ 9 = (7 ^ 8) ^ 9`), but `^` is mathematically right-associative (`7 ^ 8 ^ 9 = 7 ^ (8 ^ 9) != (7 ^ 8) ^ 9`). Which one should we use?

Comment: Can negation be stacked? i.e. is `1 - - - 1` a valid input? Doesn't negation in the output kinda negate (heh) the point of it being postfix, because it it prefix?

Answer (score 0):

## Dilapidated art gallery problem

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

In a typical art gallery problem, the objective is to place as few guards as necessary inside an arbitrary polygon so that all of it is visible by some guard. This time, we'll make some changes to simplify the task:

- The gallery can only afford to pay one guard. No more. This means that it won't be possible to keep everything in sight, so the objective becomes to maximize the amount of art visible.
- Not even a dilapidated art gallery is barbaric enough to put art on the floor, and they don't have enough money to afford pedestals, so we only care about how much wall area is visible.
- Since the art gallery doesn't even have a roof, the whole floor is visible anyways. If you are wondering how the guard manages to hover high above the gallery - he doesn't. He has a telescopic camera tied to a weather balloon. There. Problem solved. Therefore, what counts for visibility isn't occlusion. The only thing that matters is that the walls are facing the right way.
- You can assume the floor plan is a (not necessarily connected) union of rectangles. I was thinking about including diagonal walls, but this version fits better with the theme. Any internal walls have a definite thickness. If they didn't, you could just ignore them, and that's no good.
- The guard doesn't have to be inside the gallery. They can sit outside, or even lean against the walls. You, however, cannot place the guard with infinite precision. If you try to align the guard with one of the walls, they will be displaced infinitesimally in one direction chosen with uniform probability. But yes, you can try.

The input will consists of the following characters:

- The space character represents 1m x 1m of empty space. It's up to you to decide if it's inside the gallery, or outside. You may assume that the input encodes a rectangular area that includes all of the gallery floor and that all of the walls are depicted.
- `-` and `|` represent 1m x 1m squares with walls (east-west and north-south respectively) passing through their centers. Each wall will be adjoined by either the same type of wall or a corner in its lengthwise direction, and empty space in its transverse direction.
- `+` Represents a corner. Each corner will be adjoined by an east-west wall either on its east side or on its west side, but not both, and by a north-south wall either on its north side or its south side, but not both, and by empty space on the remaining two sides, and in all four diagonally neighboring tiles.

Your objective is to determine and mark all guard locations - tile centers - that maximize the number of wall segments viewed from the correct side - empty space should be marked with `.` and wall tiles should be marked with `#`.
In the event that none of the optimal spots align with tile centers, do not mark any tile as optimal. It is the user's responsibility to provide a more detailed floor plan. You may optionally display an error message in that case. If you choose so, the error message must be: displayed in every situation in which no optimal tile would have been marked; same for every input that causes it to be shown; includes at one character not allowed in any valid output.

Example cases:

```
+----+    +----+
|    |    |....|
|    | => |....|
|    |    |....|
+----+    +----+
```

The guard can be anywhere inside the gallery, but they can't lean against the wall because they might suddenly find themself on the other side of that wall unexpectedly.

```
+---+        +---+    
|   |        |   |  . 
+---+ +-+    +---+ +-+
      | | =>       | |
      | |          | |
      | |          | |
      +-+          +-+
```

In this case, the gallery consists of two separate buildings, and the guard's best spot lies outside either of them.

```
+---+
|   |
|   +-+ => error
+-+   |
  |   |
  +---+
```

In this case, there is a 1m x 2m area in which the guard can see all of the walls, but there's no way to depict that in the output. You may pass the input unmodified,  or you may output an error message.

```
+-----+    +-----+
|     |    |.   .|
| +-+ |    | +-+ |
| | | | => | | | |
| +-+ |    | +-+ |
|     |    |.   .|
+-----+    +-----+
```

This art gallery has a courtyard. Two inner walls must be left unprotected, but it doesn't matter which ones.

```
  +-+          +-+    
  | |         .#.#... 
  +-+ +-+     .###.##+
      | |     .....#.|
+-+   +-+ => +##...##+
| |          |.#..... 
+-+ +-+      +##.###. 
    | |       ...#.#. 
    +-+          +-+
```

For every wall but four, there is another wall such that exactly one of the two can be seen at any given time. As long as the other four walls are guarded, the number of walls guarded is maximized. This is also one of the rare cases where the guard can lean against a wall - if they fall through, they'll wind up guarding another wall instead.

```
+-------------+
```

This is not an art gallery. It's a fence with no inside or outside. Invalid input.

```
+---+-+---+   +
|   | |   |   |
|   | |   |   +
+---+-+---+
```

You might think this depicts two rooms with an internal wall, or three rooms with two internal walls - either way, internal walls are banned. Also, fences are banned. Invalid input.

```
+---+ +--+ +-+
|   | |  ++| |
|   +-+   |+-+
+---------+
```

This building has a clear interior and exterior, but the southern corridor is too narrow, the dent in the north-east corner is too jagged to leave enough room for art, and the nearby closet is too close to the main building. Each of these reasons suffices to make this an invalid input.

```
|---------+
| +-+     |
|    *a k |
| ei 32A  |
+-+++-+--++
```

There's a gap in the northwest corner, debris all over the floor, and the southern wall has exposed scaffolding. All wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misreading, but I feel as though there is a lot of excess information provided, while certain more basic concepts are left unexplained. For example, the rule about guard displacement being uniformly random and the size of the tiles being 1m2 seem unnecessary for computing the output, whereas the rule for what the guard sees was difficult for me to interpret. My understanding is that the guard sees infinitely far in every direction, but not through walls?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman from the third point: "Therefore, what counts for visibility isn't occlusion. The only thing that matters is that the walls are facing the right way". Are you suggesting I should reformulate that?

Comment: Yes, that part wasn't totally clear to me, and it feels like a very important detail that is somewhat buried amongst much less relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

## For How Long am I Alone? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Task

You are a factory worker, whose shift is from time *X* to time *Y*. It's a very boring job, and you want to know if any other workers are working during your shift. Given a list of start and end times for the other workers and your own shift time, output the longest amount of time that you are the only one working in the factory.

## Input

List of start and end times. Any reasonable format is allowed, such as a list of tuples representing `(startHour, startMinutes, endHour, endMinutes)` or a list of date objects.

A pair of times, which represent your own start and end times. These may be received as a tuple/list or as separate arguments. Again, the times can be passed as a tuple, date objects, or two object array representing `(hour, minutes)`, or you can pass the hours and minutes as separate arguments.

Each person starts working precisely at their start time and gets off work right when the end time starts. For example, if someone is working from 8:00 to 17:00, at 17:00 they are not considered to be at work anymore.

Each person does his shift 7 days a week.

If you choose to use date objects, the "Year" field of the date objects must always be the same across all inputs.

Note that the end time of your shift can look like it's earlier than your start time, e.g. `21:30` - `5:30`. This means that your shift starts at `21:30` at the first day and ends at `5:30` on the next day.

## Output

The longest interval in minutes in which you are the only one working in the factory.

## Test Cases

In the form of `[(hh:mm,hh:mm)...], hh:mm, hh:mm`

```
[(3:30, 12:00), (13:00, 21:40)], (8:30), (16:30) -> 60
[(1:01, 1:03), (1:04, 1:06), (1:07, 1:10)], (1:00), (1:10) -> 1
[(21:00, 5:00), (22:30, 7:00)], (0:00), (4:00) -> 0
```

## Questions

Should I keep the part about the shift being able to stretch across midnight?

Is the input specification clear enough?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Say my shift is overnight and someone has a shift that isn't overnight. How do I know what day said shift belongs to? e.g. if I'm working from `21:30` to `5:30` and I get another input as `1:00` to `4:00` how do I know if I haven't even started?

Comment: @RGS Good question. Added a part about the shifts being 7 days a week, so there is no confusion. I feel like the part about having a overnight shift might make this challenge unnecessarily complicated; What do you think?

Comment: I am not a sandbox veteran, but from my POV this challenge will have us handling intervals and do arithmetics with the interval endpoints and that is probably the main core of the challenge. But adding the overnight shifts means we are trying to intersect segments of a circumference, instead of regular intervals, which is also interesting, I think! (do you understand what I mean with this?) So maybe either remove overnight shifts or rephrase the challenge as intersecting segments of a circumference? So that it becomes more clear that it isn't just an edge case, but the core challenge itself

Comment: As for the title, I would have `"For how long am I alone"` because `"How long am I alone"` looks like you are asking for your length when you are alone, instead of the amount of time during which you will be alone.

Comment: Instead of "must always be the same across all inputs", I suggest "will always be the same across all inputs". This makes it more clear that you don't have to deal with the year.

Answer (score 0):

## Ordinal to Cardinal

Given a positive integer represented as the English spelling of an ordinal number, return the equivalent cardinal number.

### Rules

- Where an integer requires multiple words to spell, only the last word changes.
- The following integers are strongly irregular:

  - "one" becomes "first"
  - "two" becomes "second"
  - "three" becomes "third"
- Other integers take a suffix of "th", however there are a few integers that are weakly irregular:

  - "five" becomes "fif(th)"
  - "eight" becomes "eigh(th)"
  - "nine" becomes "nin(th)"
  - "twelve" becomes "twelf(th)"
  - "twenty" to "ninety" become "twentie(th)" to "ninetie(th)".
- The input can be assumed to be the English spelling of an ordinal number that follows the above rules to transform it into the equivalent cardinal number.

### Examples

- "one hundred and nineteen" becomes "one hundred and nineteenth"
- "one hundred and twenty" becomes "one hundred and twentieth"
- "one hundred and twenty one" becomes "one hundred and twenty first"

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: There are a lot of loosely related challenges, with [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4707/31625) being the closest. I don't think this is a dupe at all, though, since the amount to change is much more significant. Is there an upper limit on the input? If not, you definitely need to specify how the larger numbers might appear i.e. do we need to handle "milliard" as well as "million"?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That and the other challenge takes the numbers as digits rather than words, which IMHO is a significant difference already. As for large numbers, you can assume for the purposes of the question that any number I forgot about takes a "th" suffix.

Comment: Which integers do we need to handle? I'd suggest limiting it to, say, numbers from 1 to 99. Or if you do want all positive integers, could you please clarify how these are written out?

Comment: @xnor a) this challenge is about words, not numbers b) the rules are there, I don't understand what you're missing

Comment: @Neil Like, is "one billion, two hundred and thirty four million, five hundred and sixty seven thousand, eight hundred and ninety" a possible input, for which the output would be "one billion, two hundred and thirty four million, five hundred and sixty seven thousand, eight hundred and ninetieth"? If so, what is the exact format for such numbers? I understand that really only the last word matters for the conversion in the challenge, but it might make a difference for, say, a regex that does a replacement that might falsely trigger on something like "Duotrigintillion".

Comment: @xnor Why would it falsely trigger on duotrigintillion? Is there no duotrigintillionth?

Comment: @Neil I mean if it's part of a longer number and the regex does a replacement that doesn't check for the end of the string, but simply replaces certain sequences of characters. Duotrigintillion is an arbitrary example; I don't expect it specifically to  actually "collide" with anything useful.

Comment: @xnor Well, surely if it collides as the last word, then it will collide as an earlier word, which would be an error, according to the first rule?

Comment: @Neil Oh, you're right, that would catch it. Maybe a more useful example is "one hundred and one" wrongly being made into 'first hundred and first". In any case, I think it would be useful to either add large-valued test cases or put an upper bound.

Comment: @xnor I still don't see that it needs an upper bound. You can just assume that the rules I've given apply, even if they don't in real life for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

## Mom-rounding the time [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

## Context

Growing up with my mother, whenever she looked at a clock to check the time, she would always say *"shoot, it's already X!"* and then I would look at the clock and realize she was just rounding the time in a really weird way.

## Task

Given a time with hours and minutes, round it like my mom would. Rounding always occurs upwards. Say it is currently `H` hours and `M` minutes.

- if `M` is 0, no rounding occurs; my mom isn't that crazy;
- if `M` is 9 or less, my mom rounds to `H:15`;
- if `M` is 19 or less, my mom rounds to `H:30`;
- if `M` is 34 or less, my mom rounds to `H:45`;
- for any other value of `M`, my mom rounds to `H+1:00`.

## Input

You will take a time that needs rounding, in any sensible format. ISO strings for date/time, two integers representing hours/numbers, a string with two integers and a separator; these are all fair game.

## Output

The string `"shoot, it's already X"` with `X` replaced with the mom rounding time.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins. However, if your source code contains the substring `shoot, it's already` then you may subtract 19 from your score.

## Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##fY5RS8MwEMff8ynOgJjQtCRmBRenz3vp@6CUUTRukTSVNjCEffeatm6Oru6ejrvf/e6vG1u6Xazbt8Z8@Q51VV2RNeMU4lfIQ1M8IzTOMoog1GGvHWTwsoJlYIZRX4EFkd6gxRUub8nlYoovLuxb@rvM15EIIROEvLZ2EJ3ucLuva8/A@IcWStvo8v0b8LCKIrCm9a36rI0Dcn6DFWZ/P70lxnm9083W19v@gGwiwTmlcDzCBlYxjGkgo8VwRk92fIeTriqNI3lxDmRq9XFojNdkyCoEg@Bi/dxZEpp7EEJxPgeDZPA0gSUokc7Cwbycmv@DhWRCTmGp5HyMRybTCzgZY3De/QA) is the program I use to generate the test cases.

```
11:00 -> shoot, it's already 11:00!
 3:08 -> shoot, it's already 03:15!
 1:09 -> shoot, it's already 01:15!
13:13 -> shoot, it's already 13:30!
 2:35 -> shoot, it's already 03:00!
```

Comment: +1 because *my* mom's rounding is similarly weird too. One thing though: `shoot, it's already` has a `'` which must be escaped in many languages, and the substring condition is unfairly penalizing langauges without string literal support.

Comment: I suggest removing the [unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384) about adding text and only keep the conversion. [Bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106) are bad in general. Here it seems you try to even the playing field by [explicitly disadvantaging languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058) with string compression, but end up [making the false assumption](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067) that the substring will occur if used literally, even though some languages will need to escape the quote.

Comment: Assuming hours wrap around in 24-hour time, some test cases showing this would be good.

Comment: Those bullet-points should either be else-ifs instead of ifs or you should just define ranges. Currently a minute of `3` would first be rounded to `15` for being `<=9`, then `15` is rounded again to `30` for being `<=19`, and then again to `45` for being `<=34`. So basically: `0` remains `0`; `<=34` becomes `45`, and `>34` becomes `0` with the hour increasing, and the other bullet-points could be ignored. I think something like `M=0→H:00`; `M=[1,9]→H:15`; `M=[10,19]→H:30`; `M=[20,34]→H:45`; `M=[35,59]→H+1:00` (perhaps in text form) would be clearer imo.

Comment: @petStorm thanks for your edit but I would prefer if you did not edit any reference programs into my sandboxed posts (you may comment with a TIO link) nor edited the challenge to cope with the feedback I get from commenters, nor to include a whole "test cases" section (but you can include it in your TIO link). In particular, usually when I don't include test cases right from the start is because I want to polish the spec a bit before trying to understand what test cases are really relevant and needed.

Comment: And this is especially true because you create a whole section and then write "Here is the program _I_ used to generate the test cases" as if _you_ were _me_, which is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

## Word Grid Puzzle Iterator

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I commonly see an advert for a word-based game, where, by removing a word from a grid of letters, the remaining letters "collapse", horizontally and vertically, leading to further words being findable.

The challenge is to take in a grid of characters and a word as an input, and output the collapsed grid after that word has been removed.

Words in the grid could be oriented in any direction.

This is code-golf, usual exclusions apply.

### Example

The following set of examples follow on from each other - so the output from the first example is the input to the second.

#### AIR

In:

```
N   F   A   D   S   T
I   O   I   E   N   T
A   G   R   W   O   H
R   L   I   A   H   A
S   L   E   E   W   W
```

Out:
If the word "AIR" is removed, none of the rows or columns are empty and so the rest of the grid remains as-is:

```
N   F       D   S   T
I   O       E   N   T
A   G       W   O   H
R   L   I   A   H   A
S   L   E   E   W   W
```

#### HAIL

If the word "HAIL" is removed, the letters in the 2nd-5th columns drop down one, making the word "SNOW" accessible:

```
N                   T
I   F       D   S   T
A   O       E   N   H
R   G       W   O   A
S   L   E   E   W   W
```

#### SNOW

If SNOW is removed, the columns collapse horizontally:

```
N               T   
I   F       D   T   
A   O       E   H   
R   G       W   A   
S   L   E   E   W
```

#### THAW

If THAW is removed, the T drops down so that SLEET is now accessible:

```
N                       
I   F       D       
A   O       E       
R   G       W       
S   L   E   E   T
```

#### SLEET

Removing SLEET clears a row and a column, and so the grid collapses in both directions:

```
                    
N                   
I   F   D           
A   O   E           
R   G   W
```

#### RAIN, DEW, FOG

The remaining three vertical words (RAIN, DEW, FOG) can then be removed individually:

```
                    
                    
F   D               
O   E               
G   W
```

```
                    
                    
F                   
O                   
G
```

## Notes

In the above examples, I have not resized the arrays as the outside rows/columns are made empty; instead just leaving them blank (i.e. the final array is 6x5, as is the starting array). Your program may also do this, or it may resize the array to remove empty rows and columns if you prefer.

For example, assuming the input is a 1x5 array:

`H  A   T   C   E` removing `HAT` could become `_ _ _   C   E` or `CE`, both are valid. (underscores represent spaces for formatting purposes)

## Inputs and Outputs:

Any reasonable format is acceptable - arrays, strings, etc. But:

- you cannot assume that the orientation of the word to remove is the same as that in the input. e.g you won't get the input "LIAH" because the word HAIL is written right-to-left on the grid.
- the output must be the same format as the input (i.e. the program must accept the output from the previous iteration as the grid input to the next)
- You can assume the word will be in the grid, horizontally or vertically (not diagonally)
- Words will never contain spaces, only the letters A-Z; and if the word is found but with a space in it, then that doesn't count as matching the word

  - You can assume the case of the word will match the grid, in whatever case suits your language (UPPER, lower, camelCase, whatever)
- You can assume that the Input word will only appear once on the grid

## Sandbox Questions

- Does this feel too much like multiple challenges (find the word, collapse the array)?

Comment: I think the idea stands on its own logically, though perhaps there is a dupe out there somewhere. Separately, I think you should explain the situation where a word appears more than once. Your resizing comment also seems a bit odd: I would expect that if instead of HAIL the input was AGWOH the word wouldn't be able to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments as always. I have tried to clarify. I'm not sure what you mean about the resizing comment - only empty rows and columns can be removed; and words will always be `A-Z` (or whatever case you prefer) and must match exactly the input, in any orientation.

Comment: I see, that is what I expected, but when I read the challenge I was unsure. I think your edit makes it much clearer. (What I was trying to get at was that I expected gaps in unempty rows/columns to be "unmatchable", which I think before was made somewhat ambiguous by the wording of the purely aesthetic output)

Answer (score 0):

Comment: I like this idea. Do we have a default for taking "infinite lists" as input? I'd mildly suggest limiting the numbers to positive integers on [general principle](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/20260).

Comment: How do you propose taking an infinite list as input? I think the natural approach would use as "input" a program (or function with no arguments) that runs forever; the list would consist of the numbers that it outputs when run. (This would be sort of like a plug-in that your answer could use.) The problem is that that might make the challenge trivial.  But I'm not sure how else to take the input list.

Comment: In some languages the input could be a stream or iterator

Comment: I don't know what you want to allow, but some other possible implementations of infinite lists could be as a generator function that produces a new value on each call, or a black-box function taking a natural n and giving the n'th value.

Comment: @xnor I don't think I will limit it to positive integers because positive integers are not bounded below, meaning sequences could only increase.  This pretty radically changes the content of the challenge.

Comment: Let the first and second items of the list be `x` and `y` respectively. This checks whether `input-x` is divisible by `y-x`. (Doesn't work sometimes, I'll take a look.)

Answer (score 0):

## How many Temtem can I breed?

Temtem is a monster-catching MMORPG. Within the game you have the ability to breed two Temtem to create an egg which then hatches into the baby of its mother. The ability to do this depends on several properties of the parent Temtem:

- A Temtem has a gender, which is either male or female. To breed, you need one Temtem of each gender.
- A Temtem has one or two types. A pair of Temtem can only breed if they have a type in common.
- A Temtem has a fertility which ranges from 0 to 8. Temtem with a fertitilty of 0 can no longer breed in captivity. The fertility of each parent decreases by 1 when they breed.

The resulting Temtem inherits some of its properties from its parents.

- The baby Temtem's gender is random. For the purposes of this question, this means that you can choose the gender, but you cannot change it later.
- The baby Temtem inherits its mother's type. (This is not strictly true but it is always possible to evolve the baby to give the mother's type if necessary.)
- The baby Temtem inherits the lesser of its parents' fertility.

Simple example:

- One female Temtem with fertility 3 and one male Temtem with fertility 2 of the same type.
- Breeding reduces their fertility to 2 and 1 and we choose the baby, which also has 1 fertility, to be male.
- The female can breed again with both males, at which point all the Temtem now have 0 fertility.
- This gives you a total of five Temtem.

You challenge is to write a program or function which accepts a list of Temtem and outputs the maximum number of Temtem it is possible to breed, assuming luck is on your side.

You can use any convenient input method for the Temtem, as long as it breaks no standard loopholes. For instance, you could use a string of three or four characters encoding the gender, fertility and type(s). (Your input method must be able to support 12 different types and 132 different pairs of types.)

You can output either the total number or the number of new Temtem, or you can also output the resulting list of Temtem in the order they were born.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function wins!

Comment: Without the types this makes an interesting "limited Fibonacci-like" growth - I'd be curious to see if it had already been studied. I think adding in the types makes it more likely that brute forcing will be the best approach. I haven't done much work on this yet, so of course I could be wrong. Separately, this definitely needs a test case where inter-type breeding gives a larger result than handling each separately, though I'm pretty sure you knew that.

Answer (score 0):

> The assignment logic may be used in a planning KoTH, in which a student bot chooses a full permutation from the classes and is awarded points from what preference they get.

## Assign classes fairly and satisfyingly [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

#### Background

In a school, students are signing up for after-school classes. However, the capacity of each class is limited. In order to facilitate class assignment, each student is required to fill in a questionnaire to show his/her preference to the classes by listing all classes in decreasing order of his/her interests.

You are assigned to help assigning classes to them. You want to maximally satisfy their preferences while being fair with the assignment. A student can be assigned with multiple classes.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that receives the following input:

- a list of classes with the corresponding capacities; and
- a list of students with their corresponding preference lists,

and output or return either:

- a list of class with the list of students being assigned to that class; or
- a list of students with their assigned classes.

You may use any reasonable alternative format for both input and output, for example, apart from receiving two arrays, you may choose to receive two strings, and especially for the second input (which requires a 2-D array), you may even have an input like this (first level delimiter `\n`, second level delimiter `space`):

```
1 2 3 4
4 2 3 1
1 3 2 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

To simplify the challenge, you may assume both classes and students are 0-indexed or 1-indexed. For the use of illustrating the requirements and samples, 1-indexing is used. You may also assume that each preference list is a full permutation of all classes.

The assignment requirements are as follows:

- **Fairness**: All students must have roughly the same amount of classes assigned to them, that is, for every \$1\le i\le\text{[Number of students]}\$, $$\left|{\text{[Number of classes assigned]}_i-\frac{\sum\text{[Class capacities]}}{\text{[Number of students]}}}\right|<1.$$
- **Satisfaction**: You should fulfill the preferences as well as possible. Specifically, you should fulfill as much first preferences as possible, then as much second preferences as possible, and so on. In case of having the same preference order, the classes should be assigned on first-come-first-served basis.

The fairness rule should be taken first if it conflicts with the satisfaction rule. Test case 3 is an example of handling such conflicts.

The program should terminate in finite time for all practical sizes of inputs.

#### Test cases

**Test case 1**

Input:

```
classes = [2, 2, 2, 2],
students = [
 [1, 2, 4, 3],
 [2, 4, 1, 3],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [4, 3, 2, 1]
]
```

Output:

```
classes = [
 [1, 3],
 [2, 1],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 2]
],
students = [
 [1, 2],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 1],
 [4, 3]
]
```

Explanation:

1. It is clear that all 1st priorities can be fulfilled because all of them are different. So each student gets his 1st priority.
2. Student 1 wants Class 2 as his 2nd priority, and Class 2 still has place for him. So he gets Class 2.
3. Student 2 wants Class 4 as his 2nd priority, and Class 4 still has place for him. So he gets Class 4.
4. Student 3 wants Class 4 as his 2nd priority, but Class 4 is already full. No place for him.
5. Student 4 wants Class 3 as his 2nd priority, and Class 3 still has place for him. So he gets Class 3.
6. Now each of the students except Student 3 has 2 classes already, so by the rule of fairness they are not considered in the subsequent assignments.
7. Only Class 1 has place for Student 3, so he gets his 4th priority.

**Test case 2**

Input:

```
classes = [2, 2, 2],
students = [
 [3, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [3, 2, 1]
]
```

Output:

```
classes = [
 [1, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [1, 4]
],
students = [
 [3, 1],
 [2, 1],
 [2],
 [3]
]
```

Explanation:

1. It is clear that all 1st priorities can be fulfilled because none of the classes was chosen by 3 or more students as their 1st priorities.
2. Student 1 wants Class 1 as his 2nd priority, and Class 1 still has place for him. So he gets Class 1.
3. Student 2 wants Class 3 as his 2nd priority, but Class 3 is already full. No place for him.
4. Student 3 wants Class 3 as his 2nd priority, but Class 3 is already full. No place for him.
5. Student 4 wants Class 2 as his 2nd priority, but Class 2 is already full. No place for him.
6. Now Student 1 has 2 classes already, so by the rule of fairness he is not considered in the subsequent assignments.
7. Student 2 wants Class 1 as his 3rd priority, and Class 1 still has place for him. So he gets Class 1.
8. All classes are already full, so no more seats can be assigned. Students 3 and 4 will only get 1 class each.

**Test case 3**

Input:

```
classes = [1, 1, 1, 2],
students = [
 [1, 2, 4, 3],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [2, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 4, 1, 3]
]
```

Output:

```
classes = [
 [1],
 [3],
 [2],
 [4, 2]
],
students = [
 [1],
 [3, 4],
 [2],
 [4]
]
```

Explanation:

1. It is clear that all 1st priorities except for Student 4 can be fulfilled.
2. If we ignore Student 4 and proceed to the second round, Student 2 and 3 will occupy the remaining seats and Student 4 will not get a place (which is disallowed by the fairness rule), so the 2nd priority of Student 4 will be considered first. Since Class 4 still has place for him, he gets Class 4.
3. Student 1 wants Class 2 as his 2nd priority, but Class 2 is already full. No place for him.
4. Student 2 wants Class 4 as his 2rd priority, and Class 4 still has place for him. So he gets Class 4.
5. All classes are already full, so no more seats can be assigned. All students get 1 class each, except Student 2, who gets 2 classes.

**Test case 4**

Input:

```
classes = [1, 1, 1, 2],
students = [
 [1, 2, 4, 3],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [2, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 1, 3, 4]
]
```

Output:

```
classes = [
 [1],
 [4],
 [2],
 [2, 3]
],
students = [
 [1],
 [3, 4],
 [4],
 [2]
]
```

Explanation:

1. It is clear that all 1st priorities except for Student 4 can be fulfilled.
2. If we ignore Student 4 and proceed to the second round, Student 2 and 3 will occupy the remaining seats and Student 4 will not get a place (which is disallowed by the fairness rule), so the 2nd priority of Student 4 will be considered first. However both Classes 1 and 3 are full, he can only get Class 4.
3. The remaining place for Class 4 goes to Student 2, and we have 3 1st priorities, 1 2nd priority and 1 4th priority fulfilled.
4. But this is not the best. By breaking the first-come-first-served rule for 1st priority, we can get the best - 3 1st priorities and 2 2nd priorities fulfilled.

#### Winning Condition

This is a code-golf challenge, so the shortest submission for each language wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

## chaining couples with parity [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integers) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

### Rules

Take the \$n\$ first integers (with 0 included or not) with \$n\$ an
**even number** except 0.

The goal is to produce a (not so) *random* chain of couples with
these numbers, for example with \$n=6\$ : `(5, 4), (1, 6), (3, 2)`

But you have to respect a bit of parity and randomness :

1. Each second number in a couple must have the same parity than
   the first number of the next couple. No rule for the first number
   of the first couple and the second number of the last couple. So
   the example above is not a correct answer.

`(5, 4), (6, 1), (3, 2)` is a correct answer for \$n=6\$.

So this is a sort of parity chain.

2. First number (of the first couple) has to be chosen randomly (uniform) in the \$n\$ first integers.

### Input

An even number \$n\$ greater or equal than 2.

### Valid output examples

- Input: \$n=2\$ Outputs `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` are valid.
  `(0, 1)` and `(1,0)` are also.
- Input: \$n=4\$ Output: `(0, 1), (3, 2)` (if start with 0)
  because 1 and 3 are odd
- Input: \$n=4\$ Output: `(1, 4), (2, 3)` (if start with 0)
- Input: \$n=6\$ Output: `(0, 5), (1, 3), (4, 2)`
- Input: \$n=8\$  Output: `(6, 7), (1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 4)`

### Invalid output examples

- Input: \$n=4\$ Output:`(1, 2), (3, 4)` because 2 is even and 3
  is odd.
- Input: \$n=6\$ Output:`(5, 4), (1, 6), (3, 2)` because 4 is even and 1
  is odd and also because 6 is even and 3 is odd.

### What if \$n\$ is odd?

No rule for \$n\$ if it's odd. All outputs accepted!

### What about output's format?

No special formatting is expected. You just have to separate the
couples such that one can correctly see them.

### Sandbox Questions

Duplicate?

Comment: Use `\$` instead of `$` to use MathJax. Also, what do you exactly want by "random"? Is it acceptable to pick from two answers (e.g. pick between `(1 2)(4 3)(5 6)` and `(5 6)(4 3)(1 2)`)? Check [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/78410) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18420/78410).

Comment: @Bubbler Thx. I tried to be clearer about randomness expectations.

Comment: "First number (of the first couple) has to be chosen randomly (uniform) in the n first integers." It is still easier than having to pick from all possible answers. No problem if you intended it though.

Answer (score 0):

## Check my Knight's Tour

Given as input an `n`-by-`n` matrix of integers, check that all integers from `1` to `n²` are present, and that all pairs of consecutive integers are exactly a Knight's move apart. (For instance, a `4`-by-`4` board with the values

```
1 2 1 2
2 1 2 1
1 2 1 2
2 1 2 1
```

would meet the condition that all `1`s would have a `2` that was exactly a Knight's move away, but this would of course not constitute a Knight's Tour.) The integers `1` and `n²` do NOT need to be a Knight's move apart. You must be able to support at least 7 different values for `n` including `10`.

A Knight's move is possible between any two squares that are a Euclidean distance of √5 apart.

Output follows normal [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: I think your example would be clearer if you showed the matrix with the columns vertically stacked. It took me a while to figure out what the example was showing as is.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman My MathJax isn't good enough for that, sadly. Feel free to change all of my backquotes to backslashed dollar signs.

Comment: Maybe you can add more test-cases

Answer (score 0):

## Euler's Geometry Puzzle

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203492/eulers-geometry-puzzle)

Comment: This probably needs a description of an incircle and circumcircle. As for what you ask, personally I believe the best thing to do with challenges like this is to say "you must meet `<arbitrary precision>` for the test cases, work in general, but you need not handle floating point errors" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @FryAmTheEggman I'm not sure if I can give a good definition, so I linked the pages in wolfram mathworld.

Comment: Since it is for triangles, the definitions can be fairly simple (even if finding them is still cryptic). In the interest of allowing people to understand what the challenge asks without requiring them to go to other websites, I think you can include a brief summary of the two definitions: incircle - the largest circle that fits inside the triangle, circumcircle - the circle that passes through each of the traingle's vertices.

Comment: Done. Thanks! @FryAmTheEggman

Comment: I don't think this is a very interesting challenge, as there is very likely no other beautiful formula for such a thing as the distance between the incenter and the circumcenter, so this is 2.5 challenges in one: "find the incircle radius", "find the circumcircle radius" and "substitute both into this formula".

Comment: Hmm, but if you need to compute both the incircle radius and circumcircle radius, the formula can be simplified. (so the bytecount should be fewer than the sum of these two individual challenges, at least to me it's true) the last 0.5 is... for the context. @mypronounismonicareinstate

Comment: I think something that might help with the challenge feeling like a few stapled together would be dropping the requirement that the two radii be included in the output. That way, golfing benefits from coupling are less hampered by needing to remember/store/output intermediate values. It is definitely possible that this won't fix the problem totally, but I think it should help.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. I'll look into it tomorrow. (I'm a bit afraid if there're some much easier way to calculate that value alone)

Comment: @newbie For what it's worth, here's what a mildly golfed formula for `d` alone looks like: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BDsIgDIbvPgVHyopzAzJdsidBDoAhLlG2zHnw6bFB06Rf2/9v0/Wz35esSpqu5eGf4eaZx4Bx9CKI2HLfhCaCEEcjeNdyTp30IGgeZagMMgJI0uoGVG@Z8/reX2xi1vaoUDu0lNFUGhyIA16wO1FxRgpi1yvslUaljXOHtGy/T9ic2f/cyNZtzjtPvCoA5Qs "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks! I did some more golf and it's 66 bytes now. Would it be a better idea to output say \$R+r+d\$?

Comment: Alright, I would go with output \$d\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Rot1Rot3 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Write a program or function such that given a string \$ S \$, encode it with *Rot1Rot3*. To encode it, do the following:

1. Take \$ S\$ and partition it into blocks with \$ 3 \$ characters each. If it does not partition equally (i.e. \$ |S| \bmod 3 \neq 0 \$), take away some characters from the end of the string until it does, and form a smaller partition from the 'taken-away' characters.
2. For each individual partition, rotate it to the right by \$ 1 \$ step.
3. Finally, rotate all of the partitions together to the right by \$ 3 \$ steps, as if each partition were one character.

### Example

*Input:* `Hello, code golf!`

1. Partition it like so: `|Hel|lo,| co|de |gol|f!|` (pipes to show separation). Notice that `f!` does not form a full partition, and is therefore left as a partition with \$ 2 \$ characters instead.
2. Rotate each individual partition to the right by \$ 1 \$ step: `|lHe|,lo|o c| de|lgo|!f|`.
3. Rotate the partitions as a whole to the right by \$ 3 \$ steps: `| de|lgo|!f|lHe|,lo|o c|`.

*Final Output*:  `delgo!flHe,loo c`

### Additional Info

- You can expect any sequence of any characters, as long as they are [printable](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/it212/documents/ascii-pr.htm).
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

#### Input

```
Hello, code golf!
flog yhcrana
Rot1Rot3
abababa
import this
1
21
All animals are equal, but some animals are more equal than others.
```

#### Output

```
 delgo!flHe,loo c
yg rhcaanofl
tRoo1R3t
aabbbaa
torh tsipim
1
12
hotser.lAln aaim lsearq eluab,  utmsoae mnisalr ame eorq eluah t an
```

Answer (score 0):

## Draw a Bracket

A [bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(tournament)) is a way of organizing a tournament as a tree structure.  It follows several rounds of matches with half of the competitors being eliminated each round, until one competitor remains.

In this challenge you will be given as input a list of one digit \$(0-9)\$ integers as input representing competitors and you should output an ASCII representation of a bracket.  The exact specifications are in the **Output** section of this challenge.

For example if the input is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` then the output would be:

```
1
 1
2
  1
3
 3
4
   1
5
 5
6
  5
7
 7
8
```

In this challenge the lower number is always the winner in a matchup.

### Input

The input will always be of length \$2^n\$ for some positive integer \$n\$, and will consist entirely of one digit numbers.  You may take the integers as their representative characters instead if this pleases you.

### Output

I will explain precisely how the output is created momentarily, it is a bit hard.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a bracket.

Comment: I am worried because this says "you have a string of digits of uncertain length, and I'll explain the rest of the challenge later, it's a bit hard" and that's it.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate The length is explicitly \$2^n\$.  I do have an example which should help get the idea across.  Even though it is a simple idea it is just hard to put the idea in a very concrete specification in a ways that is not incredibly roundabout or esoteric.

Comment: @infinitezero I added an explanation of what a bracket is if that helps, I don't know if that resolves your issue.  It is hard for me to know since this is very clearly a bracket to me.

Comment: The word "bracket" is ambiguous, but I could easily understand from the word "tournament" that the figure is the result of a tournament with \$2^n\$ players where the winner is deterministic. I guess you could draw the same figure rotated 90 degrees to help understanding the task. (And I once misunderstood it as "winner is always the left one" before I saw the line under the figure. It'd be better to randomize the example input a bit to make it clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203498/are-you-ready-to-meet-the-elite-four)

Answer (score 0):

## How could these rep and scores have happened?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Challenge: Given a reputation score, a count of questions with accepted answers, and a list of net votes on questions, calculate a sequence of actions that could have produced them. To keep this simple, here's a few simplifications from how Stack Exchange actually works:

- The only things that change reputation are upvotes on questions (+10), downvotes on questions (-2), and accepting an answer to a question (+2).
- The daily cap of 200 never comes into play.
- Votes are never retracted and accepts are never rescinded.

The minimum possible reputation of 1 still applies. If there are multiple sequences of actions that can produce the given state, then your program/function should return the shortest possible sequence (or one of the shortest, if there's multiple that are tied for the shortest). If there are no sequences of actions that can produce the given state, consider that Undefined Behavior, so it doesn't matter what your program does.

Examples/test cases:

- A user has 1 reputation, hasn't accepted any answers, and has no questions. The shortest possible sequence is "".
- A user has 33 reputation, has accepted 1 answer, and has questions with scores 2 and 1. A shortest possible sequence is "upvote, upvote, upvote, accept".
- A user has 3 reputation, hasn't accepted any answers, and has a question with score -5. The shortest possible sequence is "downvote, downvote, upvote, downvote, downvote, downvote, downvote".

The standard restrictions against loopholes apply. I/O may be in any convenient format. Examples: For input, `[101,0,4,3,2,1]` or `(101,0,[4,3,2,1])` could mean a user with 101 reputation, 0 questions with accepted answers, and questions with scores 4, 3, 2, and 1. For output, the string `UDA` could mean "upvote, downvote, accept".

This is code golf, so the shortest program/function wins.

Answer (score 0):

### This Question Has _____ Views [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

[posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/this-question-has-views)

Comment: I think currently the challenge will only be who can get the shortest domain that'll respond with the output. I think you should limit the challenge to only accessing the stack exchange api, and not any other website

Comment: @CommandMaster But any other domain will be wrong as soon as the number of views goes up. The program should always print out the number of views this question has at the moment you actually run the program.

Comment: someone can register a domain which will retrive the live number

Comment: @CommandMaster that is either the "Fetching the desired output from an external source" or the "Outsourcing the real answer" loophole.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert CSV to GeoJSON

Given an input in this CSV format:

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name,Value
-37,145,Melbourne,4500000
-34,150,Sydney,5000000
```

produce this output (GeoJSON):

```js
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": "Melbourne",
                "Value: "4500000"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-37, 145]
            }
        }
    ],
...
}
```

You may assume that:

- The input will always be a well formed CSV file in this format. (No meta rows/front matter, no quoted strings, no spaces between fields, no problematic characters.)
- The input will contain one "Longitude" and one "Latitude" column, capitalised that way.
- The Latitude and Longitude columns may not be in that order, nor necessarily the first two columns.
- The number of other columns may be zero or many. They must all be converted.
- There will always be one header row. There may not be any data rows.

Notes regarding the output:

- must be valid GeoJSON (test with geojsonlint.com if you're not sure). Note: There *must* be a properties object, even if it is `{}`.
- is correct if it is semantically equivalent. (The order of keys does not matter).
- Whitespace does not matter.
- Treat all properties as strings.

Input and output in any of the standard ways for text input/output. Note the output must be *text*, not an *object*. (Ie, in JavaScript, use `JSON.stringify()`)

Comment: What's the scoring mechanism? Code Golf I assume?

Answer (score 0):

## Finitly inverese in base N [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Your task is when given a base N (you can assume it's \$ \geq2 \$) you need to output all natural numbers for which the decimal expansion of \$ \frac{1}{x} \$ in base N is finite.

### Input

You can take the base N in any reasonable format, and you also may take an additional number N, depending on what output format you chose.

### Output

You have 3 options for the output format:

- Take a number `n` and output the `n`-th number in the sequence
- Take a number `n` and output first n numbers in the sequence
- Take no additional input and output the list indefinitely

## Test Cases

```
10 -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 25, 32, 40, 50, 64, 80, 100, 125, 128, 160, 200, 250, 256, 320, 400, 500, 512, 625, 640, 800, 1000, 1024, 1250, 1280, 1600, 2000, 2048, 2500, 2560, 3125, 3200, 4000, 4096, 5000, 5120, 6250, 6400, 8000, 8192, 10000, ...]
2 -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, ...]
```

Comment: So basically numbers such that their set of prime factors is a subset of N's set of prime factors? (assuming no repetitions in sets)

Comment: I'm not sure, but from what I've seen it seems like it

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204302/calculate-the-digit-sum)

Comment: Can we require inputs to be padded for us?

Comment: Can we output via a digit array?

Comment: What do you mean by output via a digit array? Like [2,4] instead of 24?

Comment: What do you mean by `Are you sure you mean base 19, not base 10?`? In base 10 `16` isn't a digit, and [1, 16] isn't a number

Comment: Why base 19? That seems pretty arbitrary

Comment: It's the smallest base for which the sum of any two digits in base 10 fit in

Comment: Looks like a cool challenge :)  I think a few more test cases would be useful. Some slightly larger test cases would also be great

Comment: I doubt that there is any approach other than "take the decimal digits, sum the digits as vectors and convert from base 19" here.

Answer (score 0):

## Making a programable computing chip

Make a programable chip with 8000 commands ROM and 48 16-bit unsigned words RAM initalized with zero.

---

These commands should be supported:

```
a = b + c  # mod 65536
a = b - c
a = b * c
a = b / c  # undefined behavior if c==0
a = b % c
a = b > c  # return 0 or 1
a = b >= c
a = b == c
a = b != c
if a goto b 
if !a goto b
call a, b  # store ip of next command to b and goto a, then can return
input a
output a
a = [b] # You can decide constant k and l, such that [kn+l] is rn. 
[a] = b # Using undefined [n] is UB
```

where `a, b, c` can be `r0-r47` or a constant of a 16-bit integer or the ip of a command. Writing to a constant is a nop, so `input 42` discards an input. Mixing ip and integer, running out of commands are undefined behavior.

For example,

```
L1: input r1
    r0 = r0 + r1
    output r0
    if !0 goto L1
    r2 = r1 + L1
```

takes input, and output sum of all inputs modulo 65536. `r2 = r1 + L1` is undefined behavior, but since it's never executed it's not a problem.

---

The circuit consists of controlled gates `(x,y,c,t)`, meaning that wire `x` and wire `y` are connected if wire `c` was active(t=1) or inactive(t=0), and programable wire `(x,y,0,0)`, meaning that wire `x` and wire `y` can be programmed to be connected.

At the beginning, none of the wires, except IO wires(discuss later), is active. In each step, any wire connected to wire 0, whether directly or indirectly, is active.

IO is used to connect multiple such component. It contains 18 wires, where 16 of them store an integer to be passed, and two `A` and `B` meaning if there's data on the wire.
When sender send, sender negate `A`; when reciever recieve, `B` negated. Therefore, there's data on the wire iff `A!=B`.

We write A on input, B on input, A on output, and B on output of the chip, as 4, 8, 5, 9, respectively, and the 16-bit input on 16-31, output on 32-47. You can active wires where you are expected to read from, but your chip should handle with another such chip (so if you write to input, you should handle cases when output is inputted).

For example, `{(0,5,4,1),(0,8,9,1)}` output zero whenever recieving an input.

---

You should submit a circuit (a set of 4-elem tuples) and a compiler. Smallest circuit win.

Answer (score 0):

## Ariadne's String [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Given a \$ 20 \times 20 \$ grid, start at any arbitrary point. Then starting from this point, draw a sequence of straight lines each attached to two points on the grid. In addition, the lines must be in strictly increasing length, and such that no two intersect or touch each other. Call the number of lines drawn \$ n \$. The diagram below shows an example of a smaller \$ 5 \times 5 \$ grid, where \$ n = 5 \$. However, the maximum length for a \$ 5 \times 5 \$ grid is actually \$ n = 9 \$ *(Try to find it yourself!)*.

[image]

This is [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), meaning the answer with the largest \$ n \$ wins!

*Checker program coming soon*

### Sandbox

- Anything unclear?
- How to position image on the right and text on the left (it looks better)

Comment: Related: [A226595](http://oeis.org/A226595), which lists exact values up to grid size 15. The C++ program's comment says it took 1001 minutes (~17 hours) to get the exact answer for 15.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert NFA to DFA as quickly as possible.

**Input**

Your input will be an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). In order to be able to test your code, it needs to be able to handle an NFA in the following format. This is taken  directly from [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/automata-1.14/doc/chap2.html#X821C3B3687B1F2FF) (and slightly simplified).

```
Automaton( Type, Size, Alphabet, TransitionTable, Initial, Accepting )
```

For the input, Type will always be "nondet".  Size is a positive integer representing the number of states of the automaton. Alphabet is the number of letters of the alphabet. TransitionTable is the transition matrix. The entries are lists of non-negative integers not greater than the size of the automaton are also allowed. Initial and Accepting are, respectively, the lists of initial and accepting states.

Example input:

```
Automaton("nondet", 4, 2, [[[], [2], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4]],
                                [[], [1, 3, 4], [1], [2, 4]]], [1], [2, 3])
```

This is slightly easier to read as a transition table.

```
   |  1    2             3                4
--------------------------------------------------
 a |      [ 2 ]         [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]   [ 2, 4 ]   
 b |      [ 1, 3, 4 ]   [ 1 ]            [ 2, 4 ]   
Initial state:    [ 1 ]
Accepting states: [ 2, 3 ]
```

**Output**

Your output must be a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that is **equivalent** to the input NFA.  There is no need for your DFA to be minimal. For the output, Type will always be "det".  Size is a positive integer representing the number of states of the automaton. Alphabet is the number of letters of the alphabet. TransitionTable is the transition matrix. The entries are non-negative integers not greater than the size of the automaton. The states should be labelled by consecutive integers.  Initial and Accepting are, respectively, the lists of initial and accepting states.  In the case of the example above, this would be:

```
Automaton("det", 2, 2, [[2, 2], [2, 2]], [1], [])
```

As a transition table this is:

```
   |  1  2  
-----------
 a |  2  2  
 b |  2  2  
Initial state:   [ 1 ]
Accepting state: [  ]
```

(It is now clear this is a DFA that will not accept any input strings.)

## Test cases:

1. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",2,4,[[[1], [2]], [[2], []], [[2], []] , [[1], [2]]],[1],[1, 2]))
```

As a transition matrix:

```
   |  1       2
-------------------
 a | [ 1 ]   [ 2 ]   
 b | [ 2 ]           
 c | [ 2 ]           
 d | [ 1 ]   [ 2 ]   
Initial state:    [ 1 ]
Accepting states: [ 1, 2 ]
```

Here is the diagram of the NFA.

[image]

Output:

```
Automaton("det",3, 4,[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1],[1, 2])
```

As a transition matrix:

```
   |  1  2  3  
--------------
 a |  1  2  3  
 b |  2  3  3  
 c |  2  3  3  
 d |  1  2  3  
Initial state:    [ 1 ]
Accepting states: [ 1, 2 ]
```

Here is the diagram of the DFA.

[image]

2. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",7,4,[[[1, 3, 4, 5], [2], [3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [], []], [[2, 3, 4, 7], [3], [], [], [3, 7], [3, 4], []], [[2, 3, 5, 6], [3], [], [3, 6], [], [], [3, 5]], [[1, 3, 6, 7], [2], [3], [], [], [3, 6], [3, 7]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Output:

3. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",12, 4,[[[1, 3, 5, 6], [2, 4, 7, 8], [3], [6], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 7], [4, 8], [], []], [[2, 3, 5, 10], [3, 4, 7, 12], [6], [], [4, 7], [3, 10], [], [4, 12], [3, 5], [4, 12], [4, 7], []], [[2, 3, 6, 9], [3, 4, 8, 11], [6], [], [3, 9], [4, 8], [4, 11], [], [4, 11], [3, 6], [], [4, 8 ]], [[1, 3, 9, 10], [2, 4, 11, 12], [3], [6], [4, 11], [4, 12], [], [], [3, 9], [3, 10], [4, 11], [4, 12]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Output:

```
Automaton("det",39, 4,[[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 24, 7, 8, 22, 20, 8, 32, 18, 18, 3, 19, 25, 18, 19, 20, 25, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25, 24, 23, 5, 2, 35, 32, 19, 19, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36], [1, 38, 1, 23, 15, 9, 11, 26, 23, 28, 26, 10, 9, 26, 1, 3, 22, 26, 3, 28, 22, 23, 1, 15, 3, 3, 15, 1, 28, 27, 10, 27, 23, 23, 38, 15, 28, 15, 28], [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 12, 6, 6, 31, 31, 37, 37, 30, 5, 5, 29, 37, 3, 21, 4, 21, 4, 4, 4, 29, 30, 29, 1, 5, 29, 37, 5, 3, 29, 3, 3, 2, 2], [1, 16, 3, 4, 3, 21, 7, 18, 33, 39, 14, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 34, 21, 34, 3, 19, 19, 16, 38, 15, 4, 33, 17, 18, 33, 34, 16, 19, 34, 38, 39]],[7],[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39])
```

4. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",25,4,[[[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 8, 9], [3, 5, 10, 11], [6], [7], [3, 5, 6, 10, 18], [3, 5, 7, 11, 19], [4, 8], [4, 9 ], [5, 10], [5, 11], [4, 5, 8, 10, 22], [4, 5, 9, 11, 23], [5, 10], [5, 11], [], [], [5, 10, 18], [5, 11, 19], [5, 10, 22], [5, 11, 23 ], [], [], [], []], [[2, 3, 6, 13], [3, 4, 8, 15], [4, 5, 10, 17], [7], [], [4, 5, 8, 10, 18], [3, 5, 13, 17, 21], [5, 10], [4, 15], [], [5, 17], [3, 5, 6, 10, 22], [4, 5, 15, 17, 25], [4, 8], [5, 17], [5, 10], [], [], [5, 17, 21], [], [5, 17, 25], [5, 10, 18], [], [5, 10, 22], []], [[2, 3, 7, 12], [3, 4, 9, 14], [4, 5, 11, 16], [7], [], [3, 5, 12, 16, 20], [4, 5, 9, 11, 19], [4, 14], [5, 11], [5, 16], [], [4, 5, 14, 16, 24], [3, 5, 7, 11, 23], [5, 16], [4, 9], [], [5, 11], [5, 16, 20], [], [5, 16, 24], [], [], [5, 11, 19], [], [5, 11, 23]], [[1, 3, 12, 13], [2, 4, 14, 15], [3, 5, 16, 17], [6], [7], [4, 5, 14, 16, 20], [4, 5, 15, 17, 21], [5, 16], [5, 17], [], [], [3, 5, 12, 16, 24], [3, 5, 13, 17, 25], [4, 14], [4, 15], [5, 16], [5, 17], [], [], [], [], [5, 16, 20], [5, 17, 21], [5, 16, 24], [5, 17, 25]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25])
```

Output:

```
Automaton("det",266,4,[[1, 127, 50, 50, 115, 249, 50, 8, 257, 10, 151, 12, 13, 14, 81, 78, 34, 106, 137, 107, 21, 22, 82, 89, 71, 43, 43, 62, 63, 63, 44, 10, 179, 171, 214, 265, 206, 38, 137, 152, 21, 151, 71, 22, 41, 41, 47, 13, 49, 50, 50, 210, 50, 210, 116, 90, 64, 49, 207, 207, 207, 62, 232, 64, 64, 89, 151, 236, 236, 70, 71, 236, 116, 260, 128, 75, 13, 38, 77, 133, 14, 82, 13, 13, 77, 235, 64, 64, 231, 206, 138, 91, 91, 206, 90, 264, 137, 169, 10, 10, 41, 71, 232, 228, 232, 21, 21, 107, 106, 110, 111, 266, 256, 114, 114, 116, 251, 251, 116, 114, 114, 111, 266, 260, 122, 182, 127, 128, 129, 213, 132, 132, 129, 49, 49, 138, 138, 138, 249, 71, 43, 43, 210, 235, 183, 214, 132, 265, 206, 138, 232, 64, 64, 153, 153, 64, 152, 152, 82, 236, 236, 82, 116, 116, 64, 207, 266, 64, 231, 169, 171, 250, 227, 70, 175, 175, 176, 10, 47, 178, 178, 110, 111, 266, 260, 122, 266, 127, 213, 49, 49, 152, 257, 153, 257, 90, 90, 183, 250, 264, 62, 228, 229, 82, 82, 206, 64, 266, 249, 249, 249, 242, 213, 214, 64, 116, 114, 114, 50, 50, 236, 236, 261, 115, 152, 251, 8, 228, 229, 229, 231, 232, 237, 235, 235, 236, 237, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 242, 242, 242, 115, 251, 249, 250, 116, 116, 116, 207, 64, 265, 266, 257, 256, 266, 264, 261, 260, 264, 265, 266], [1, 125, 1, 114, 114, 121, 115, 3, 23, 19, 13, 15, 230, 28, 201, 202, 16, 84, 123, 103, 105, 208, 114, 84, 172, 199, 199, 119, 83, 83, 123, 170, 16, 31, 27, 26, 25, 104, 102, 23, 28, 13, 120, 208, 48, 103, 19, 230, 239, 1, 114, 218, 115, 219, 82, 140, 23, 208, 204, 216, 216, 119, 174, 119, 119, 84, 13, 115, 115, 50, 120, 50, 82, 204, 262, 79, 230, 104, 203, 85, 28, 114, 230, 230, 203, 3, 23, 119, 96, 96, 96, 123, 102, 140, 208, 3, 200, 200, 98, 97, 103, 120, 119, 120, 119, 28, 105, 103, 105, 54, 3, 23, 141, 1, 250, 50, 82, 114, 50, 1, 250, 3, 3, 219, 219, 125, 54, 263, 124, 124, 27, 124, 223, 208, 239, 25, 208, 208, 120, 120, 217, 217, 217, 120, 120, 142, 142, 141, 140, 140, 174, 174, 174, 204, 216, 23, 119, 23, 250, 114, 114, 250, 162, 162, 159, 205, 159, 159, 208, 123, 170, 1, 219, 50, 208, 208, 123, 177, 177, 19, 170, 173, 172, 172, 199, 199, 23, 186, 185, 184, 184, 23, 120, 216, 23, 140, 208, 120, 1, 3, 119, 120, 114, 114, 250, 239, 119, 3, 121, 3, 120, 219, 212, 212, 23, 50, 1, 250, 1, 114, 50, 114, 219, 114, 23, 114, 3, 120, 114, 114, 208, 119, 125, 121, 3, 50, 54, 120, 3, 120, 121, 3, 120, 218, 219, 217, 114, 114, 3, 1, 250, 250, 250, 253, 252, 173, 172, 120, 125, 3, 3, 219, 219, 3, 54, 3], [1, 1, 249, 249, 6, 1, 1, 247, 7, 130, 167, 17, 11, 66, 33, 33, 131, 136, 10, 32, 150, 9, 112, 36, 149, 112, 149, 56, 167, 37, 181, 130, 35, 147, 139, 51, 139, 11, 10, 234, 147, 37, 148, 113, 136, 136, 146, 24, 249, 1, 1, 249, 249, 249, 139, 6, 238, 127, 134, 238, 134, 9, 148, 238, 134, 167, 36, 50, 249, 247, 73, 249, 51, 139, 112, 167, 76, 76, 11, 167, 80, 73, 67, 66, 66, 135, 58, 58, 112, 139, 233, 100, 100, 2, 6, 95, 10, 32, 130, 130, 99, 94, 94, 56, 149, 150, 147, 150, 136, 51, 51, 51, 7, 51, 51, 51, 7, 6, 139, 139, 139, 2, 58, 134, 139, 7, 1, 112, 112, 249, 238, 238, 112, 249, 127, 238, 233, 238, 1, 149, 112, 149, 249, 135, 7, 139, 238, 51, 139, 238, 112, 238, 233, 234, 234, 134, 234, 190, 112, 50, 249, 73, 139, 51, 238, 134, 51, 134, 148, 32, 147, 145, 145, 145, 258, 259, 180, 130, 146, 189, 189, 51, 51, 134, 134, 139, 2, 1, 249, 127, 249, 191, 191, 191, 188, 188, 188, 188, 198, 197, 196, 196, 195, 187, 187, 139, 233, 134, 127, 127, 127, 49, 249, 139, 243, 211, 211, 211, 210, 210, 210, 210, 95, 209, 241, 209, 126, 117, 117, 9, 112, 112, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 127, 127, 127, 249, 249, 249, 7, 7, 1, 247, 51, 139, 211, 134, 134, 51, 51, 7, 7, 2, 126, 145, 139, 247, 51, 51], [1, 51, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 50, 73, 61, 11, 12, 40, 109, 101, 93, 45, 18, 19, 20, 21, 64, 161, 29, 193, 118, 193, 65, 11, 42, 19, 59, 30, 46, 163, 164, 163, 40, 39, 57, 46, 42, 246, 60, 18, 21, 61, 158, 72, 50, 51, 53, 53, 3, 55, 55, 57, 246, 156, 64, 65, 64, 155, 64, 65, 11, 29, 68, 69, 236, 160, 72, 73, 55, 157, 11, 154, 154, 40, 11, 46, 160, 225, 192, 192, 86, 87, 88, 157, 118, 155, 19, 39, 74, 161, 239, 92, 92, 166, 254, 20, 144, 88, 240, 65, 109, 108, 21, 21, 50, 50, 73, 73, 50, 247, 236, 73, 161, 72, 3, 5, 54, 86, 239, 3, 51, 50, 64, 64, 161, 165, 64, 157, 161, 245, 165, 60, 64, 51, 240, 161, 240, 4, 144, 51, 55, 57, 73, 55, 57, 157, 157, 155, 57, 64, 156, 64, 87, 118, 160, 161, 248, 163, 164, 165, 168, 164, 168, 60, 19, 108, 3, 3, 72, 64, 60, 19, 194, 194, 61, 59, 247, 247, 193, 193, 5, 74, 7, 69, 244, 69, 156, 240, 65, 74, 74, 246, 143, 219, 86, 88, 144, 222, 222, 226, 72, 60, 239, 52, 54, 143, 239, 72, 72, 215, 221, 219, 224, 219, 220, 221, 222, 239, 220, 215, 222, 54, 160, 160, 161, 64, 64, 160, 68, 236, 236, 236, 160, 239, 240, 244, 245, 246, 69, 72, 161, 51, 160, 50, 50, 248, 118, 226, 255, 255, 248, 248, 160, 160, 245, 245, 72, 72, 236, 236, 236]],[12],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266])
```

5. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",38,4,[[[1, 3, 7, 8], [2, 4, 9, 10], [3, 5, 11, 12], [4, 6, 13, 14], [7], [8], [3, 5, 7, 11, 23], [3, 5, 8, 12, 24], [4, 6, 9, 13, 25], [4, 6, 10, 14, 26], [5, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], [6, 14], [4, 5, 9, 11, 31], [4, 5, 10, 12, 32], [5, 6, 11, 13, 33], [5, 6, 12, 14, 34], [6, 13], [6, 14], [], [], [5, 11, 23], [5, 12, 24], [6, 13, 25], [6, 14, 26], [5, 11, 31], [5, 12, 32], [6, 13, 33], [6, 14, 34], [6, 13, 25], [6, 14, 26], [], [], [6, 13, 33], [6, 14, 34], [], []], [[2, 3, 7, 16], [3, 4, 9, 18], [4, 5, 11, 20], [5, 6, 13, 22], [8], [], [4, 5, 9, 11, 23], [3, 5, 16, 20, 28], [5, 6, 11, 13, 25], [4, 6, 18, 22, 30], [6, 13], [5, 20], [], [6, 22], [3, 5, 7, 11, 31], [4, 5, 18, 20, 36], [4, 6, 9, 13, 33], [5, 6, 20, 22, 38], [5, 11], [6, 22], [6, 13], [], [6, 13, 25], [5, 20, 28], [], [6, 22, 30], [6, 13, 33], [5, 20, 36], [], [6, 22, 38], [5, 11, 23], [6, 22, 30], [6, 13, 25], [], [5, 11, 31], [6, 22, 38], [6, 13, 33], []], [[2, 3, 8, 15], [3, 4, 10, 17], [4, 5, 12, 19], [5, 6, 14, 21], [8], [], [3, 5, 15, 19, 27], [4, 5, 10, 12, 24], [4, 6, 17, 21, 29], [5, 6, 12, 14, 26], [5, 19], [6, 14], [6, 21], [], [4, 5, 17, 19, 35], [3, 5, 8, 12, 32], [5, 6, 19, 21, 37], [4, 6, 10, 14, 34], [6, 21], [5, 12], [], [6, 14], [5, 19, 27], [6, 14, 26], [6, 21, 29], [], [5, 19, 35], [6, 14, 34], [6, 21, 37], [], [6, 21, 29], [5, 12, 24], [], [6, 14, 26 ], [6, 21, 37], [5, 12, 32], [], [6, 14, 34]], [[1, 3, 15, 16], [2, 4, 17, 18], [3, 5, 19, 20], [4, 6, 21, 22], [7], [8], [ 4, 5, 17, 19, 27], [4, 5, 18, 20, 28], [5, 6, 19, 21, 29], [5, 6, 20, 22, 30], [6, 21], [6, 22], [], [], [3, 5, 15, 19, 35], [3, 5, 16, 20, 36], [4, 6, 17, 21, 37], [4, 6, 18, 22, 38], [5, 19], [5, 20], [6, 21], [6, 22], [6, 21, 29], [6, 22, 30], [], [], [6, 21, 37], [6, 22, 38], [], [], [5, 19, 27], [5, 20, 28], [6, 21, 29], [6, 22, 30], [5, 19, 35], [5, 20, 36], [6, 21, 37], [6, 22, 38]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38])
```

[Output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W37GjgyTwy/)

6. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",67,4,[[[1, 3, 8, 9], [2, 4, 10, 11], [3, 5, 12, 13], [4, 6, 14, 15], [5, 7, 16, 17], [8], [8], [3, 5, 8, 12, 28], [3, 5, 9, 13, 29], [4, 6, 10, 14, 30], [4, 6, 11, 15, 31], [5, 7, 12, 16, 32], [5, 7, 13, 17, 33], [6, 14], [6, 15], [ 7, 16], [7, 17], [4, 5, 10, 12, 40], [4, 5, 11, 13, 41], [5, 6, 12, 14, 42], [5, 6, 13, 15, 43], [6, 7, 14, 16, 44], [6, 7, 15, 17, 45], [7, 16], [7, 17], [], [], [5, 7, 12, 16, 28, 32, 52], [5, 7, 13, 17, 29, 33, 53], [6, 14, 30], [6, 15, 31], [7, 16, 32], [7, 17, 33], [5, 7, 12, 16, 40, 44, 56], [5, 7, 13, 17, 41, 45, 57], [6, 14, 42], [6, 15, 43], [7, 16, 44], [7, 17, 45], [6, 7, 14, 16, 30, 32, 60], [6, 7, 15, 17, 31, 33, 61], [7, 16, 32], [7, 17, 33], [], [], [6, 7, 14, 16, 42, 44, 64], [6, 7, 15, 17, 43, 45, 65], [7, 16, 44], [7, 17, 45], [], [], [7, 16, 32, 52], [7, 17, 33, 53], [7, 16, 44, 56], [7, 17, 45, 57], [7, 16, 32, 60], [7, 17, 33, 61], [7, 16, 44, 64], [7, 17, 45, 65], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[2, 3, 8, 19], [3, 4, 10, 21], [4, 5, 12, 23], [5, 6, 14, 25], [6, 7, 16, 27], [8], [], [4, 5, 10, 12, 28], [3, 5, 19, 23, 35], [5, 6, 12, 14, 30], [4, 6, 21, 25, 37], [6, 7, 14, 16, 32], [5, 7, 23, 27, 39], [7, 16], [6, 25], [], [7, 27], [3, 5, 8, 12, 40], [4, 5, 21, 23, 47], [4, 6, 10, 14, 42], [5, 6, 23, 25, 49], [5, 7, 12, 16, 44], [6, 7, 25, 27, 51], [6, 14], [7, 27], [7, 16], [], [6, 7, 14, 16, 30, 32, 52], [5, 7, 23, 27, 35, 39, 55], [7, 16, 32], [6, 25, 37], [], [7, 27, 39], [6, 7, 14, 16, 42, 44, 56], [5, 7, 23, 27, 47, 51, 59], [7, 16, 44], [6, 25, 49], [], [7, 27, 51], [5, 7, 12, 16, 28, 32, 60], [6, 7, 25, 27, 37, 39, 63], [6, 14, 30], [7, 27, 39], [7, 16, 32], [], [5, 7, 12, 16, 40, 44, 64], [6, 7, 25, 27, 49, 51, 67], [6, 14, 42], [7, 27, 51], [7, 16, 44], [], [], [7, 27, 39, 55], [], [7, 27, 51, 59], [], [7, 27, 39, 63], [], [7, 27, 51, 67], [7, 16, 32, 52], [], [7, 16, 44, 56], [], [7, 16, 32, 60], [], [7, 16, 44, 64], []], [[2, 3, 9, 18], [3, 4, 11, 20], [4, 5, 13, 22], [5, 6, 15, 24], [6, 7, 17, 26], [8], [], [3, 5, 18, 22, 34], [4, 5, 11, 13, 29], [4, 6, 20, 24, 36], [5, 6, 13, 15, 31], [5, 7, 22, 26, 38], [6, 7, 15, 17, 33], [6, 24], [7, 17], [7, 26 ], [], [4, 5, 20, 22, 46], [3, 5, 9, 13, 41], [5, 6, 22, 24, 48], [4, 6, 11, 15, 43], [6, 7, 24, 26, 50], [5, 7, 13, 17, 45], [7, 26], [6, 15], [], [7, 17], [5, 7, 22, 26, 34, 38, 54], [6, 7, 15, 17, 31, 33, 53], [6, 24, 36], [7, 17, 33], [7, 26, 38], [], [ 5, 7, 22, 26, 46, 50, 58], [6, 7, 15, 17, 43, 45, 57], [6, 24, 48], [7, 17, 45], [7, 26, 50], [], [6, 7, 24, 26, 36, 38, 62], [5, 7, 13, 17, 29, 33, 61], [7, 26, 38], [6, 15, 31], [], [7, 17, 33], [6, 7, 24, 26, 48, 50, 66], [5, 7, 13, 17, 41, 45, 65], [7, 26, 50], [6, 15, 43], [], [7, 17, 45], [7, 26, 38, 54], [], [7, 26, 50, 58], [], [7, 26, 38, 62], [], [7, 26, 50, 66], [], [], [7, 17, 33, 53], [], [7, 17, 45, 57], [], [7, 17, 33, 61], [], [7, 17, 45, 65]], [[1, 3, 18, 19], [2, 4, 20, 21], [3, 5, 22, 23 ], [4, 6, 24, 25], [5, 7, 26, 27], [8], [8], [4, 5, 20, 22, 34], [4, 5, 21, 23, 35], [5, 6, 22, 24, 36], [5, 6, 23, 25, 37], [6, 7, 24, 26, 38], [6, 7, 25, 27, 39], [7, 26], [7, 27], [], [], [3, 5, 18, 22, 46], [3, 5, 19, 23, 47], [4, 6, 20, 24, 48], [4, 6, 21, 25, 49], [5, 7, 22, 26, 50], [5, 7, 23, 27, 51], [6, 24], [6, 25], [7, 26], [7, 27], [6, 7, 24, 26, 36, 38, 54], [6, 7, 25, 27, 37, 39, 55], [7, 26, 38], [7, 27, 39], [], [], [6, 7, 24, 26, 48, 50, 58], [6, 7, 25, 27, 49, 51, 59], [7, 26, 50], [7, 27, 51], [], [], [5, 7, 22, 26, 34, 38, 62], [5, 7, 23, 27, 35, 39, 63], [6, 24, 36], [6, 25, 37], [7, 26, 38], [7, 27, 39], [5, 7, 22, 26, 46, 50, 66], [5, 7, 23, 27, 47, 51, 67], [6, 24, 48], [6, 25, 49], [7, 26, 50], [7, 27, 51], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [7, 26, 38, 54], [7, 27, 39, 55], [7, 26, 50, 58], [7, 27, 51, 59], [7, 26, 38, 62], [7, 27, 39, 63], [7, 26, 50, 66], [7, 27, 51, 67]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67])
```

[Output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2V5CN57GDv/)

7. Input:

```
Automaton("nondet",96,4,[[[1, 3, 9, 10], [2, 4, 11, 12], [3, 5, 13, 14], [4, 6, 15, 16], [5, 7, 17, 18], [6, 8, 19, 20], [7 ], [8], [3, 5, 9, 13, 33], [3, 5, 10, 14, 34], [4, 6, 11, 15, 35], [4, 6, 12, 16, 36], [5, 7, 13, 17, 37], [5, 7, 14, 18, 38], [6, 8, 15, 19, 39], [6, 8, 16, 20, 40], [7, 17], [7, 18], [8, 19], [8, 20], [4, 5, 11, 13, 49], [4, 5, 12, 14, 50], [5, 6, 13, 15, 51], [5, 6, 14, 16, 52], [6, 7, 15, 17, 53], [6, 7, 16, 18, 54], [7, 8, 17, 19, 55], [7, 8, 18, 20, 56], [8, 19], [8, 20], [], [], [5, 7, 13, 17, 33, 37, 65], [5, 7, 14, 18, 34, 38, 66], [6, 8, 15, 19, 35, 39, 67], [6, 8, 16, 20, 36, 40, 68], [7, 17, 37], [7, 18, 38], [8, 19, 39], [8, 20, 40], [5, 7, 13, 17, 49, 53, 73], [5, 7, 14, 18, 50, 54, 74], [6, 8, 15, 19, 51, 55, 75], [6, 8, 16, 20, 52, 56, 76], [7, 17, 53], [7, 18, 54], [8, 19, 55], [8, 20, 56], [6, 7, 15, 17, 35, 37, 81], [6, 7, 16, 18, 36, 38, 82], [7, 8, 17, 19, 37, 39, 83], [7, 8, 18, 20, 38, 40, 84], [8, 19, 39], [8, 20, 40], [], [], [6, 7, 15, 17, 51, 53, 89], [6, 7, 16, 18, 52, 54, 90], [7, 8, 17, 19, 53, 55, 91], [7, 8, 18, 20, 54, 56, 92], [8, 19, 55], [8, 20, 56], [], [], [7, 17, 37, 65], [7, 18, 38, 66 ], [8, 19, 39, 67], [8, 20, 40, 68], [7, 17, 53, 73], [7, 18, 54, 74], [8, 19, 55, 75], [8, 20, 56, 76], [7, 17, 37, 81], [7, 18, 38, 82], [8, 19, 39, 83], [8, 20, 40, 84], [7, 17, 53, 89], [7, 18, 54, 90], [8, 19, 55, 91], [8, 20, 56, 92], [8, 19, 39, 67], [8, 20, 40, 68], [], [], [8, 19, 55, 75], [8, 20, 56, 76], [], [], [8, 19, 39, 83], [8, 20, 40, 84], [], [], [8, 19, 55, 91], [8, 20, 56, 92], [], []], [[2, 3, 9, 22], [3, 4, 11, 24], [4, 5, 13, 26], [5, 6, 15, 28], [6, 7, 17, 30], [7, 8, 19, 32], [8 ], [], [4, 5, 11, 13, 33], [3, 5, 22, 26, 42], [5, 6, 13, 15, 35], [4, 6, 24, 28, 44], [6, 7, 15, 17, 37], [5, 7, 26, 30, 46], [7, 8, 17, 19, 39], [6, 8, 28, 32, 48], [8, 19], [7, 30], [], [8, 32], [3, 5, 9, 13, 49], [4, 5, 24, 26, 58], [4, 6, 11, 15, 51], [ 5, 6, 26, 28, 60], [5, 7, 13, 17, 53], [6, 7, 28, 30, 62], [6, 8, 15, 19, 55], [7, 8, 30, 32, 64], [7, 17], [8, 32], [8, 19], [], [6, 7, 15, 17, 35, 37, 65], [5, 7, 26, 30, 42, 46, 70], [7, 8, 17, 19, 37, 39, 67], [6, 8, 28, 32, 44, 48, 72], [8, 19, 39], [7, 30, 46], [], [8, 32, 48], [6, 7, 15, 17, 51, 53, 73], [5, 7, 26, 30, 58, 62, 78], [7, 8, 17, 19, 53, 55, 75], [6, 8, 28, 32, 60, 64, 80], [8, 19, 55], [7, 30, 62], [], [8, 32, 64], [5, 7, 13, 17, 33, 37, 81], [6, 7, 28, 30, 44, 46, 86], [6, 8, 15, 19, 35, 39, 83], [7, 8, 30, 32, 46, 48, 88], [7, 17, 37], [8, 32, 48], [8, 19, 39], [], [5, 7, 13, 17, 49, 53, 89], [6, 7, 28, 30, 60, 62, 94], [6, 8, 15, 19, 51, 55, 91], [7, 8, 30, 32, 62, 64, 96], [7, 17, 53], [8, 32, 64], [8, 19, 55], [], [8, 19, 39, 67], [7, 30, 46, 70], [], [8, 32, 48, 72], [8, 19, 55, 75], [7, 30, 62, 78], [], [8, 32, 64, 80], [8, 19, 39, 83], [7, 30, 46, 86], [], [8, 32, 48, 88], [8, 19, 55, 91], [7, 30, 62, 94], [], [8, 32, 64, 96], [7, 17, 37, 65], [8, 32, 48, 72], [8, 19, 39, 67], [], [7, 17, 53, 73], [8, 32, 64, 80], [8, 19, 55, 75], [], [7, 17, 37, 81], [8, 32, 48, 88], [8, 19, 39, 83], [], [7, 17, 53, 89], [8, 32, 64, 96 ], [8, 19, 55, 91], []], [[2, 3, 10, 21], [3, 4, 12, 23], [4, 5, 14, 25], [5, 6, 16, 27], [6, 7, 18, 29], [7, 8, 20, 31], [8], [], [3, 5, 21, 25, 41], [4, 5, 12, 14, 34], [4, 6, 23, 27, 43], [5, 6, 14, 16, 36], [5, 7, 25, 29, 45], [6, 7, 16, 18, 38], [6, 8, 27, 31, 47], [7, 8, 18, 20, 40], [7, 29], [8, 20], [8, 31], [], [4, 5, 23, 25, 57], [3, 5, 10, 14, 50], [5, 6, 25, 27, 59], [ 4, 6, 12, 16, 52], [6, 7, 27, 29, 61], [5, 7, 14, 18, 54], [7, 8, 29, 31, 63], [6, 8, 16, 20, 56], [8, 31], [7, 18], [], [8, 20 ], [5, 7, 25, 29, 41, 45, 69], [6, 7, 16, 18, 36, 38, 66], [6, 8, 27, 31, 43, 47, 71], [7, 8, 18, 20, 38, 40, 68], [7, 29, 45], [8, 20, 40], [8, 31, 47], [], [5, 7, 25, 29, 57, 61, 77], [6, 7, 16, 18, 52, 54, 74], [6, 8, 27, 31, 59, 63, 79], [7, 8, 18, 20, 54, 56, 76], [7, 29, 61], [8, 20, 56], [8, 31, 63], [], [6, 7, 27, 29, 43, 45, 85], [5, 7, 14, 18, 34, 38, 82], [7, 8, 29, 31, 45, 47, 87], [6, 8, 16, 20, 36, 40, 84], [8, 31, 47], [7, 18, 38], [], [8, 20, 40], [6, 7, 27, 29, 59, 61, 93], [5, 7, 14, 18, 50, 54, 90], [7, 8, 29, 31, 61, 63, 95], [6, 8, 16, 20, 52, 56, 92], [8, 31, 63], [7, 18, 54], [], [8, 20, 56], [7, 29, 45, 69], [8, 20, 40, 68], [8, 31, 47, 71], [], [7, 29, 61, 77], [8, 20, 56, 76], [8, 31, 63, 79], [], [7, 29, 45, 85], [8, 20, 40, 84], [8, 31, 47, 87], [], [7, 29, 61, 93], [8, 20, 56, 92], [8, 31, 63, 95], [], [8, 31, 47, 71], [7, 18, 38, 66], [], [8, 20, 40, 68], [8, 31, 63, 79], [7, 18, 54, 74], [], [8, 20, 56, 76], [8, 31, 47, 87], [7, 18, 38, 82], [], [8, 20, 40, 84], [8, 31, 63, 95], [7, 18, 54, 90 ], [], [8, 20, 56, 92]], [[1, 3, 21, 22], [2, 4, 23, 24], [3, 5, 25, 26], [4, 6, 27, 28], [5, 7, 29, 30], [6, 8, 31, 32], [8], [8], [4, 5, 23, 25, 41], [4, 5, 24, 26, 42], [5, 6, 25, 27, 43], [5, 6, 26, 28, 44], [6, 7, 27, 29, 45], [6, 7, 28, 30, 46], [7, 8, 29, 31, 47], [7, 8, 30, 32, 48], [8, 31], [8, 32], [], [], [3, 5, 21, 25, 57], [3, 5, 22, 26, 58], [4, 6, 23, 27, 59], [4, 6, 24, 28, 60], [5, 7, 25, 29, 61], [5, 7, 26, 30, 62], [6, 8, 27, 31, 63], [6, 8, 28, 32, 64], [7, 29], [7, 30], [8, 31], [8, 32], [6, 7, 27, 29, 43, 45, 69], [6, 7, 28, 30, 44, 46, 70], [7, 8, 29, 31, 45, 47, 71], [7, 8, 30, 32, 46, 48, 72], [8, 31, 47], [8, 32, 48], [], [], [6, 7, 27, 29, 59, 61, 77], [6, 7, 28, 30, 60, 62, 78], [7, 8, 29, 31, 61, 63, 79], [7, 8, 30, 32, 62, 64, 80], [8, 31, 63], [8, 32, 64], [], [], [5, 7, 25, 29, 41, 45, 85], [5, 7, 26, 30, 42, 46, 86], [6, 8, 27, 31, 43, 47, 87], [6, 8, 28, 32, 44, 48, 88], [7, 29, 45], [7, 30, 46], [8, 31, 47], [8, 32, 48], [5, 7, 25, 29, 57, 61, 93], [5, 7, 26, 30, 58, 62, 94], [6, 8, 27, 31, 59, 63, 95], [6, 8, 28, 32, 60, 64, 96], [7, 29, 61], [7, 30, 62], [8, 31, 63], [8, 32, 64], [8, 31, 47, 71], [8, 32, 48, 72 ], [], [], [8, 31, 63, 79], [8, 32, 64, 80], [], [], [8, 31, 47, 87], [8, 32, 48, 88], [], [], [8, 31, 63, 95], [8, 32, 64, 96 ], [], [], [7, 29, 45, 69], [7, 30, 46, 70], [8, 31, 47, 71], [8, 32, 48, 72], [7, 29, 61, 77], [7, 30, 62, 78], [8, 31, 63, 79], [8, 32, 64, 80], [7, 29, 45, 85], [7, 30, 46, 86], [8, 31, 47, 87], [8, 32, 48, 88], [7, 29, 61, 93], [7, 30, 62, 94], [8, 31, 63, 95], [8, 32, 64, 96]]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96])
```

8. The DFA for 7 plus the NFAs/DFAS for 8, 9, 10, 11 are [here](https://gist.github.com/Anush-ccgc/2fa45d31934e7b7062a6140d634c79fa/archive/fd668ccf06dbef6534be937c6d1ba22bbcf24b6b.zip) as they are too big to paste. For 12, 13, 14, 15 I have only included the NFAs. The files have names k6dfa, k7nfa, k7dfa etc. As an example, the input for problem 7 is k7nfa and the output is k7dfa.  Hopefully the rest of the names are clear.  If your code is correct for problems 1-11, I am happy to believe it is correct in general.

## Score

I will time your code on test cases 1..15 from above of increasing size. Your score will be the largest test case your code can process in less than 10 minutes.  If two answers get to the same size then the one that is fastest on that largest test case wins. The test machine is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz. You can use at most 16 of its cores.

## Testing

I will check your answers (for the smaller cases) using [AreEquivAut](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/automata-1.14/doc/chap4.html#X8346D1B17DBF96E7) .

[Thank you to Christian Sievers for the example NFAs.]

Comment: What does "the largest test case" mean? Does this task really have no pathological and trivial cases?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Thanks for reading the draft so far! I should number the cases but it means, considering the inputs in the order I have given them (there will be more once I work out where I can upload them to), stop at the first one that takes more than 10 minutes using your code. The one just before is the largest one. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was not able to actually read the draft, as the only thought the words "DFA" and "NFA" induce in my mind is "something complicated related to regex".

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate ah. They are really much simpler.  I will include some pictures and a description too.  You can think of DFAs as a really simple programming language.  But do you know where I can upload a 30MB  text file to link to? Or a 6MB compressed file

Comment: (I can also understand the words "deterministic/nondeterministic finite automaton", but I have no idea how to use them to do anything useful other than simply applying them) I guess I don't know. (didn't want to simply leave you waiting for an answer indefinitely)

Comment: So the output doesn't need to be minimal and just needs to be equivalent to the expected output, right? (Guessing so because the example at the top could have been `Automaton("det", 1, 2, [[1], [1]], [1], [])` if I'm understanding the syntax correctly) And there's a redundant `[3]` in the example input NFA, and you need to format the test inputs as code because plain `[1]`s and `[2]`s are messing up with Markdown.

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you for reading it!  I have updated the question. Please let me know if there are any other problems.

Comment: Some are still not fixed: example input NFA's `[3]`, test case 1's input is not code-blocked, and test case 2's output is lost.

Comment: @Bubbler Hopefully all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Improved image sampling [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Quoting from the ImageMagick documentation of the very simple `-sample` resizer, "You can think of the image as being divided into an array of regions, and one pixel from each region is selected for the resulting image". Unfortunately, it uses a bad algorithm for choosing the one pixel: it chooses the middle one.

In this challenge, you have to write a program that takes an image and a positive integer \$N\$ (\$N\$ divides the height and the width) as input and outputs the image downscaled by the factor \$N\$. In the output image, every pixel must be taken from the corresponding \$N\times N\$ square in the original image.

[image gallery and settings used]

This is tagged [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most upvotes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed Point of cos(x)

Fixed points are any such values where, given a function `f`, `x = f(x) = f(f(x)) = . . .`

There exists a "fixed point" for the cosine function, where `x = cos(x) = cos(cos(x))= . . .`  (you may have unknowingly come across this by repeatedly pressing "cos" on a scientific calculator).

Using the knowledge that `x = f(x)`, one can think of a fixed point as the intersection of the graphs of `y = x` and `y = f(x)`. If we let `f(x)=cos(x)`, the graph looks like this:

[image: img]

Your task is to calculate the `x`-value of the fixed point of `cos(x)` `0.73908513 . . .`  to at least 3 digits' precision (i.e. at least as far as `0.739`).

### Rules

- No input is to be taken for the program
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins

---

## Questions for Sandbox:

- Is the question clear enough as it is written?
- I have searched, but I am still paranoid: is this a duplicate?
- Are the tags [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) suitable? Or should I also include [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)?
- Should I allow input? It seems unnecessary for solving the problem to me
- How far should the precision be extended?

Comment: Very nice question! I think the code-golf tag is suitable for all code-golf challenge. P. S. If I'm getting it right one can repeatedly take cosine to solve this right?

Comment: I think this would be a more interesting challenge if the question were: "Given a function f(x), find a fixed point of f". In its current state, this challenge simplifies to: "print the number `0.739`"

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive That is correct

Comment: Who cast the downvote?

Comment: @mathjunkie I think that was already done [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150186/find-a-fixed-point), and besides, ideally they would actually calculate the value instead of simply printing it

Comment: I thought I remembered this being a duplicate, but I see you've searched already, and I didn't find anything on a quick look. I'd suggest having the output be something like 100 digits of precision to discourage hardcoding, or give the required precision as an input, though these do mean floating-point won't work.

Comment: Wait, I found the duplicate: [Approximate the Dottie number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137572/approximate-the-dottie-number)

Answer (score 0):

## Boolean Variable Satisfiability [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You are given a logical expression containing 'true', 'false', 'variable' and some common boolean operators. Assuming that all variables are independent and can be freely set to either true or false, is it possible assign values to the variables such that the expression evaluates to true?

For example, the expression `true and variable and not variable` can indeed evaluate to true (if the first variable is true and the second is false). However, the expression `false and variable` cannot ever evaluate to true, regardless of what values you set the variable to.

Note that you are not required to construct a solution; you only need to determine whether or not it exists.

## Input

You are given an expression in [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), using the following symbols:

- `T` - True
- `F` - False
- `V` - Variable
- `&` - Logical AND
- `|` - Logical OR
- `^` - Logical XOR
- `!` - Logical NOT

As an example, `TFV!T^|&` represents the expression `true and (false or (not variable xor true))`.

## Output

The program should output a truthy value iff the expression can be evaluated to true for some set of variable assignments. Otherwise, a falsy value should be outputted.

## Examples

Here are a few example expressions and their expected outputs:

```
TF&
False

FV|V&
True

VV!&
True

VV^!
True

VV&F|VVT|!&V!&&
False

VV&F|VVT|!&V!^&
True

TFV!T^|&
True

VT|!V&F|VF&!T^^
False
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

### Sandbox Comments

I've written this as if I would post it right away. However, seeing as this is the first challenge I've written for this site, any and all input is welcome so as to make sure it's of an acceptable standard.

Comment: Thanks you for using the sandbox.

Comment: One thing that bothers me here is [the combination of two tasks](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319): a) parsing the RPN b) finding if the expression is satisfiabiable.

Comment: So every appearance of `V` is independent of each other? Then it can be solved in O(n) by resolving each inner node into T/F/V on the fly. Cool challenge. But as Adám said, the task right now is two tasks combined, and we want to get it focused to b). My suggestion is to allow the programs to take *any unambiguous format that can describe a statement* as input. That includes RPN, PN, fully parenthesized infix, and (most notably) a syntax tree.

Answer (score 0):

## Constellation Enumeration in Game of Life

Yet another trivial Conway's Game of Life challenge.

A stable [constellation](https://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Still_life#Constellations) is a still life that is composed of two or more non-interacting objects.

You task is to take the valid object list, and output a list of all possible constellations. The objects cannot be rotated or reflected. All of the objects are still lives themselves.

A sample implementation is [here](https://github.com/dvgrn/b3s23life/blob/master/enumerate-constellations/build-constellation.py).

### Sandbox

- Any advices on the input and output format? Plain text, RLE, or every Golly-accepable form?
- Any test cases?
- Other recommendations.

Comment: What would the scoring mechanism be? Code Golf?

Comment: @mathjunkie Damn, I forgot to specify! Code-golf, obviously.

Comment: The recommended I/O format is "any sensible format that can describe GoL states". Also, the challenge needs much more detail. How exactly should we combine the input objects? Should we follow a strict order in generating them? Is there a limit in output grid size? How many outputs should we generate? First N? Infinity? We don't want to read such a long sample implementation, especially one that has an external dependency (do you see `import golly as g` at the top?).

Comment: A challenge needs to be self-contained. You need to briefly include what GoL is, what the rules are, what a still life is, and whatever concept you need in order to describe the task and I/O format. You might as well need to (at least roughly) describe the algorithm in the sample implementation in English words.

Answer (score 0):

## Fetch me some data [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

This is the fifth post for the [second RGS's Golfing Showdown](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18874/75323).

## Task

Write some code to fetch the *updated* total number of confirmed infected cases in a territory. The territory you choose to fetch data for will influence your score, so keep that in mind.

## Input

Your code takes no input.

## Output

You should output an integer or any other sensible representation of it.

## Rules

### Fetching the data

The data you fetch must be fetched from a URI that must have been online at least since the 25th of April of 2020. You may fetch the most recent data or the data for a specific date, as long as in that date, your territory has a non-zero number of total confirmed cases.

### Scoring and Territory

The territory you fetch data for must be a territory listed in the [WHO daily situation reports](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports/) and the numbers you fetch for a given date must be within 10% of the WHO numbers for the same date.

Your score will be the number of bytes *minus* the length of the longest common substring between your code and the territory you pick, case insensitive.

E.g. If my program is `abcdefghijklmno` and my territory is `Italy` I get to shave 2 bytes of my score because of the common substring `il` (or `al`).

## Sandbox

Are the rules clear enough and well-specified enough?

Comment: I understand now, I think. I read "The territory you choose to fetch data for will influence your score, so keep that in mind." and assumed that you meant that the size of the data we fetch will be part of our score. You should probably make it explicit that the size of any file fetched won't be part of our score if that's what you intend.

Comment: "Your score will be the number of bytes minus the length of the longest common substring between your code and the territory you pick, case insensitive." Are you trying to do this so, say, `wget Italy` will be the same size as `wget UnitedStates`? I think instead you should make it a requirement that the name of your territory is included in your program, and then remove the number of bytes in your territory name.

Comment: The number of confirmed cases in China has almost stopped increasing. Can we assume it won't increase by 10% and thus create an offline solution?

Answer (score 0):

Comment: might be too similar to previous [mutual quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine) challenge?

### Collaboration/quasi-quine challenge

Write a valid submission (A) which prints the code for another competitor's valid submission (B). The languages used in A and B must be different.

#### Clarifying rules

If B prints the code for a third submission, C, it is not required that A and C be different languages. Similarly, the authors of A and B must be different, but A and C need not be. (More different languages/authors score higher, however.)

The shortest chain is for A to print B and B to print A.

Note that if A prints B, and B prints C, but C is not valid for some reason, then neither A nor B are valid either.

It is acknowledged that the validity of your submission may change over time, due to factors beyond your control. Try not to let this worry you too much. :)

### Input

None

### Output

Just the code described above. Nothing extraneous.

### Scoring

Scoring is (A + L) * 100 + C where:

- A is the number of distinct authors that directly or indirect print your solution. So if you are Q, and Z=>X=>Q=>X, your "A" is 2. (Each submission only has one author, the "answerer".)
- L is the number of distinct languages in your quine circle, along the same lines as for authors. (Each submission only has one language. "Distinct" means really different, not just different versions or implementations of the same languages.)
- C is the length of your solution in bytes.

(So, for a given circle of quines, all the submissions will have similar scores, with the length of the submission as tie-break.)

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: I like it when your score improves if you use more languages. Any reason why you didn't include that?

Comment: Oh, what would an example of that be? I did consider something like having your score improve, the longer the chain is. Like, your score is the sum of the length of all the submissions divideded by the square of the number of participants or something.

Comment: That would be nice, but I wouldn't know how to balance it well. Just a thought.

Comment: This seems to me like a chicken-and-egg situation. How could the first posted answer be valid if there are no `B` answers to print the code for?

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161757/31625) is another similar challenge. It had several problems that I think might occur again with your current setup. I'd recommend giving the criticism and answers there a read over.

Comment: @mathjunkie It wouldn't. I don't think that's inherently problematic, it's just an interesting bootstrapping challenge.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first question, so I don't know what *exactly* I should ask, but I will try. Please advise.

---

## Russian roulette

It's [Russian roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette)! The rules are simple. Shoot a revolver with `n` slots for bullets and one round inside at your head and you *might not die*!

### Task:

Make a program that takes integer `n` (you can assume that 10<=n<=128) as input and outputs nothing.

> but how do I tell if I'm dead?

The program generates a random number x in the range 0 - (n) inclusive. If x=n the revolver fires and the program exits with an error (you die). Otherwise the program exits normally.

Standard loopholes forbidden, etc.

[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)
[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)
[error-message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-message)
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Sandbox questions:

- This question is short. What can I explain better or add?
- What are good tags to add?
- Should I make it code-golf or popularity contest? Both?
- Too easy?
- This is a joke, will it be misinterpreted?

Comment: So do we choose our own value for n, or is there some value you want us to use.

Comment: I think this challenge is extremely similar to this one: [Make your code error but only sometimes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203261/make-your-code-error-but-only-sometimes)

Comment: @mathjunkie I saw that, but this question is more specific for how it should function.

Comment: @Lyxal Originally I thought I'd let the answerers choose, but to make the question different from *Make your code error but only sometimes* I'll revise the question to take `n` from the player.

Comment: is that 0-n or 1-n inclusive, exclusive, or half-open? Also, some languages give error messages when they exit with failure.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I meant to say you can choose. Fixing.

Comment: I don't think allowing to choose is a good idea. If anything, I would prefer 0-(n-1), as that is the most common and easiest to work with.

Comment: I suggest tagging it code-golf instead of popularity-contest because popcons are netoriously difficult to do right.

Comment: Pseudocode of (likely) most answers you will get: `1/(rand()%n);`

Comment: @lyxal but maybe I should make it popularity-contest and encourage people to vote for ones that do *not* follow `1/(rand()%n)`?

Comment: [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204320/russian-roulette)

Answer (score 0):

### Revisit sum

---

**Why is this language specific?**

As much as much as I like challenges to be language agnostic if this challenge were language agnostic it would most certainly be a duplicate of the add two numbers challenge due to our current duplicate policy.  And for most languages adding two numbers and adding several numbers are no different.  Revisit is not one of those languages.

---

In [Revisit](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/revisit) adding two numbers is easy.

```
+@
```

does the trick.  However in this challenge we are going to ask you to do something much more difficult.  Take a an arbitrary number of positive integers as input and output the sum of all them.

Your answer should be functioning revisit as per revisit version 0.1.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers are scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

Answer (score 0):

## Compass and straightedge segment reduction [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

You are given two points at distance 1, a compass and a straightedge. The challenge is, given a positive integer \$N\$, to find the shortest segment possible to obtain by drawing no more than \$N\$ lines or circles. A segment is defined as a pair of two points such that there is a line connecting them.

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

### Sandbox stuff

- Certain details of compass-and-straightedge constructions are not specified yet.
- Should I allow assuming normal floating point math to be exact, or to require proper arbitrary precision?
- Is the answer trivial? I know that you can, for example, obtain geometric progressions with factor that seems to be \$\tan(x)\$ (and thus perhaps it's optimal to first bisect an angle for a while, then subtract it from a straight angle, and then [do this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281923/557261)).

More importantly, is this possible? I assume it is, because it seems possible to calculate everything necessary for the basic constructions:

- It's (easily) possible to compare lines and circles for equality
- It's possible to calculate the parameters of a line passing through 2 points.
- It's possible to calculate the parameters of a circle - that is, find the point and the radius given the point and the radius.
- It's possible to calculate the point of intersection between 2 lines (if it exists).
- It's possible to calculate the points of intersection between a line and a circle.
- It's possible to calculate the points of intersection between 2 circles.

Is that enough for a proof?

Answer (score 0):

## Continue an arithmetic-geometric progression [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

<sup>note: not related to [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) arithmetic-geometric *sequences*</sup>
An arithmetic progression has the property that \$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}2\$ - that is, every term is the *arithmetic* mean of its neighbours.
A geometric progression has a similar property: \$a_n = \root\of{a_{n-1}\cdot a_{n+1}}\$ - every term is the *geometric* mean of its neighbours.

There's also the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) \$AGM(x, y)\$! It's defined as follows: define two sequences as \$a_0 = x, g_0 = y, a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+g_n}2, g_{n+1}=\root\of{a_n g_n}\$. The sequences converge to the same number, the arithmetic-geometric mean of \$x\$ and \$y\$.

Now I can define another progression: an arithmetic-geometric progression has the property that \$a_n = AGM(a_{n-1}, a_{n+1})\$.

As input you are given two real numbers - the first two terms of an arithmetic-geometric progression. The challenge is to find the third one with absolute or relative error not exceeding \$10^{-5}\$ (and output it).

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Emulate a Schmitt trigger

Given low and high cutoff points, and a list of input readings, generate a list of output states at those points.

- If an input reading is greater than the high cutoff point then the output is always in the high cutoff state.
- If an input reading is lower than the low cutoff point then the output is always in the low cutoff state.
- At least one of the above comparisons must be a strict inequality. (Please make both comparisons strict unless this would consume additional bytes.)
- If the initial reading is between the two cutoff points the the output must be deterministic (i.e. the same for each run with the same inputs).
- In all other cases the output remains in the same state.
- It is valid for both cutoff points to be the same value.
- The input readings may be taken in any convenient format, but it must be capable of handling at least 94 different values.
- [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) The output for each input reading must be one of two distinct values.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Subtract a list [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You are given a list of boolean values as input. You have to find its difference.

The difference of a list of one value is equal to the value itself. The difference of a list with \$N\$ values is defined as $$(\text{the difference of the first }\lfloor\frac{N}2\rfloor\text{ items}) -  (\text{the difference of the last }\lceil\frac{N}2\rceil\text{ items})$$

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

[todo: examples]

Answer (score 0):

## Analyze the flow

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[counting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204694/analyze-the-flow)

Comment: From the example, it looks like the path can wrap around the edges of the grid. I think you should mention that explicitly. I also think you should define "tributary"

Comment: Yes, you can wrap around and this is the only reason why I use a toroidal grid. 
I've added the definition of "tributary"... I know it's still informal but I don't want to lose readability, I've tried to go more formal but the need of a lot of definitions arises.
Is it still unclear?

Comment: @math junkie anyway thanks for the grammar corrections, also in the main post :D

Answer (score 0):

There are \$a\$ honest man(always tell the truth), \$b\$ dishonest man(always tell lie), and \$c\$ random man(tell random Y/N). How many times at least should you ask one of them a yes/no question to guarantee you get knowledge of who they are? You may assume that it's possible.

Test cases:

```
(a,b,c) -> ans
(1,1,0) -> 1
(1,1,1) -> 3
(0,0,2) -> 0
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Notes:

- I don't know if there's clever way, but anyway brute-force work
- It's enough if you can only ask an expression about who they are. If you ask them "what will A answer if I ask B" the answer is just "(A is liar) xor B". "Did A tell lie when answering B" is just "(A's answer) xor B". Questions about the current ask or future ask may lead to paradox and are not allowed.
- Actually it's possible to identify them iff there are less than half of random answerer, or an edge case that all are random answerers. Only considering honest and random, if there are more honest than random, ask them same question and do a majority vote gets answer to the question. If there are same honest and random, and random tell as if they are honest and real honest are random, you can't tell the difference.

Comment: I think the wording is a little confusing. Will there always be one of each? Will your program be given a list of `a`, `b`, and `c`s as input? Also, you may want to look at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73143/knights-and-knaves) question to check if it's similar to yours.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes `a,b,c` are given, and possibly zero. Link don't match this problem well

Comment: Wouldn't it require at least 4 questions for the test case (1, 1, 1)? How to solve in 3?

Comment: @user202729 http://brainden.com/forum/topic/373-the-liar-the-truth-tellerand-the-random-answerer/ (not [wiki answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardest_Logic_Puzzle_Ever) as it assume answer from random is either true or false)

Comment: Oh wiki also has a standard solution

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms [Formal description (according to my understanding of the statement)](https://pybin.pw/AP30-guauPKExtWVm_4Vf71Ui9j9)

Answer (score 0):

Posted: [SELECT ALL FROM SelectQL WHERE (answer="short" OR NOT length=10000)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204924/select-all-from-selectql-where-answer-short-or-not-length-10000)

Comment: What happens if the specified table doesn't exist?

Comment: The usual SQL statement is `SELECT * FROM data`, where `*` is the wildcard operator. Also, the set of parentheses after "WHERE" is not mandatory in usual SQL. I guess these changes make the challenge easier to parse.

Comment: @Λ̸̸   Yeah, it's to make it slightly easier. However, I could change it. Which I will!

Comment: @Lyxal undefined, the programs should assume that the table is in the database

Comment: Consider deleting this post, as the challenge is already on main

Answer (score 0):

The game of scrabble is played by placing lettered tiles on a grid to form words. The words being formed must read from left to right, or up to down on the grid. The words must appear in the official Scrabble dictionary, and all letters placed on the grid must be part of a valid word. This challenge will focus on a specific technique for playing a simplified version of Scrabble.

A useful technique when playing Scrabble is to add a single letter to an existing word that is already on the board to form a new word. Write a program or function that, when given a dictionary, finds the longest series of words that can be formed by adding a single letter to another word to form a new word.

### Example

You are given the following dictionary:

```
at
ate
rate
elate
crate
belate
belated
```

Your submission should output:

```
['at', 'ate', 'rate', 'crate']
```

An invalid output would be:

```
['at', 'ate', 'elate', 'belate', 'belated']
```

because `'elate'` cannot be formed by adding a single letter to `'ate'`.

Note that this challenge is not about finding the longest word that can be formed by adding a single letter to another word, but about finding the longest chain of words that can be formed in such a way. Which means that this answer:

```
['elate', 'belate', 'belated']
```

is wrong, because it only has three steps, whereas the first example has four.

### Winning Criteria

Code-golf, so shortest code wins. I/O is flexible. Standard loopholes apply. Take dictionary as a list, file, delimited string, or whatever you want. Output can be sent to stdout, returned as a single string (with delimiter), or list of strings.

### Test Cases

TODO

Answer (score 0):

## Golf me a  <sup>Bookmarklet</sup> Quine

Given a javascript program (or any utf-8 text) of arbitrary length, output it in my simplified version of [URI form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), like a bookmarklet. You can use https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ as reference. Output should be in the form

`javascript:`[input with percent-encoding for special characters]

Special characters are any character that is not

- Alphabetic (upper or lower)
- a digit
- the characters `.`,`-`,`_`, or `~`   (period, hyphen, underscore, tilde)

Your program "should convert all other characters to bytes according to UTF-8, and then percent-encode those values"<sup>[w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data)</sup>

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP). [*source*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)

Lowercase hex is okay, but uppercase is preferred.

This is code golf, standard loopholes are prohibited, programs should handle input up to 20 lines and output in a single line.

### The Twist (so it's not a duplicate)

If run with no input or just a newline (your choice), the program should output itself in the same format as if the program's source was inputted normally.

### Examples

```
In                                              Out

[blank]                                         javascript:[the%20program%27s%20source]
g/re/p                                          javascript:g%2Fre%2Fp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ     javascript:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ
alert("test!")                                  javascript:%7Balert(%22test!%22)
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

---

### sandbox questions

- What should I add?
- What tags does this need?
- Are my examples inconsistent?
- What parts of the challenge are redundant?

Answer (score 0):

## Uniform necklace sampling [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

The challenge is, given a number \$N\$, to produce a random binary [necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) of length \$N\$. All possible necklaces must have the same probability of being chosen.

[TODO: more about necklaces]

### Scoring

Solutions are compared first by asymptotic memory complexity in \$N\$ (lower is better), and, in case of a tie, by size (lower is better).

### Sandbox stuff

(I *do* intend to use code-golf as only a tiebreaker)

- How to tag this question the most correctly?

Comment: Not time complexity? It's trivial to do this in O(n) memory (I think that is optimal, because (as far as I know) it's not possible to (deterministically) check if a string is a necklace in less memory) by iterating over all necklaces, count number of those = C (C can be represented in N bits), generate a random number x in the range 1..C, then count again and pick the xth necklace.

Comment: @user202729 I tried to pick a combinatorial object that prevents a linear-memory solution (any suggestions?). I guess these answers should win (with [code-golf] used to compare them - this is mostly [restricted-memory] code-golf, but submissions that aren't good enough aren't disqualified).

Answer (score 0):

## [Posted.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205155/golf-me-a-text-editor)

Comment: Are the prompts mandatory, should they be in that format? (or maybe all the input should be on one line like `?> [line]:[content]`

Comment: This seems like an interesting challenge, but I think some details are missing. For starters, you should provide a full list of commands that our program must support, as well as a few more examples

Comment: @mathjunkie What do you think now?

Comment: Looks better. However, [Bonuses in Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/65425) is high on the list of "Things to avoid when writing challenges". I would recommend either including those bonus tasks as part of the main challenge or removing them completely

Comment: Ahh, good ol' edlin.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve some diplomatic issues

You are given a set of moves in a theoretical *Diplomacy* game.  We're not going to handle validation of moves being legal or not, simply attempt to resolve a turn.

Here are the simplified rules to Diplomacy ([full rules here](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/diplomacy_rules.pdf)):

- There are two types of units: Armies and Fleets.  Armies can only move on land, Fleets on land and in the sea.  You can safely ignore this, because we're assuming that all of the moves you've been given are at least theoretically valid.
- There are four types of moves: Hold (stay in place), Move, Support (a certain other unit), Convoy.
- When two or more units end up in the same country, whichever unit has the most support stays.  Each unit without the most support (or each unit tied for the most) returns to its original country.  A unit which is not Moving and which is not tied for the most support is Dislodged.
- A Fleet can Convoy an Army through its space to another space.  That convoy is cancelled if the Fleet is Dislodged.  Only a Fleet in a sea space can Convoy.
- A unit can support another unit holding or moving into an adjacent country if it can move into that country (Armies can't Support Fleets in the sea).
- A supporting unit which is attacked ceases to support, unless it is supporting an attack on the unit attacking it.  If it is dislodged, it ceases to support in any case.
- The Beleaguered Garrison rule: If a unit is attacked by two units with the same amount of support, the attacked unit is not Dislodged, and the attackers return to their original countries.

You will receive a list of moves.  Each move will be in the following format:

```
Power Unit_type Origin_country Move_type Destination_country
```

There is no Destination_country if a unit holds (or you can insert a placeholder).  Destination_country for Support or Convoy is the Origin_country of the unit being Supported or Convoyed.  For example, you could get:

```
E F Eng M Pic
F A Pic H
G A Bel S Eng
```

This means:

```
English Fleet in the English Channel Moves to Picardy
French Army in Picardy Holds
German Army in Belgium Supports the Fleet in the English Channel to Move to Picardy
```

Your output should be the location of each unit after the move.  Any Dislodged unit should be marked as such.

## Output format:

```
Power Unit_type Country Dislodged?
```

For the example given above, the output should be:

```
E F Pic
F A Pic D
G A Bel
```

The more difficult part of this is in regards to convoys.  A convoy fails if there is no valid path for the army to take.  For instance, if we have:

```
E F Nth C Den
E A Den M Hol
F F Eng M Nth
F F Bel S Eng
```

The French fleets dislodge the English Fleet in the North Sea, and the convoy does not take place.  But if we also had

```
E F Hel C Den
```

There would still be a valid path for the English Army and the convoy would succeed.

## Paradoxes

Be warned, there are paradoxes in Diplomacy.  These are to be treated as undefined behaviour; any output is acceptable where

1. Each unit is listed
2. There is only one non-dislodged unit per country
3. In any country with a dislodged unit there is a non-dislodged unit
4. Each non-moving unit is listed in its origin country
5. Each moving unit is listed either in its origin country or its destination country

Note that, in particular, each unit being in its starting country is a valid output.

## Adjacency list

For use with convoys, it's helpful to know which countries are adjacent to which other countries.  (Everything is assumed to be valid, but it may not be clear whether a convoy with a single cut link is still possible otherwise).

You may assume that this list is available to you in any format: a function that takes two countries and returns true/false, a variable, a file, etc.  In any case, the list itself does not add to your byte count.

[To be added]

## Input/Output Formats

You can use any Input/Output formats you choose, as is standard.

## Questions for the sandbox

- How much clearer does my description of the rules of Diplomacy need to be?
- Does this sound like an interesting challenge?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)

Answer (score 0):

## [_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205422/zero-the-byte-eventually)

Comment: What kind of numbers can be in the sequence?

Comment: @xnor Integers, basically.

Comment: Would the test cases that time out, `1,2` and `7,4`, be excluded by "the input will always be provided in a way such that it won't take forever to zero the accumulator"? No product of exclusively odd numbers can end up being divisible by a power of 2.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thanks for nothing that; I've removed these test cases.

Comment: Now this post is zeroed eventually

Answer (score 0):

## Enforce Social Distancing! [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Related to [Maintain Social Distancing!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204957/maintain-social-distancing).

As in that challenge, there is a 2-dimensional array of 1s and 0s representing people. In it, social distancing is maintained if and only if all 1s are at least 6 squares apart, where distance metric used is \$|\Delta x| + |\Delta y|\$ (rectilinear or Manhattan).

The challenge here is to *move* some people in a given 2D array so that social distancing is maintained. It's guaranteed that it's possible to do so. Your program's score on a given input is the total distance moved by all people.

Your program's running time must not exceed 10 seconds on any of the test cases.

This is tagged [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery), so there is a large set of inputs your programs will be tested on [TODO: actually create it]. The program with the lowest total score on all of these inputs wins.

### Sandbox stuff

- Is this currently a bad idea for the reasons specified by Shaggy in the following comment?

  > I *am* sorry but I have downvoted this for what others may perceive to be a trivial reason: Code Golf is one of the few things I have left where I can escape how fucked my world has become; I absolutely *do not* want to come here to be reminded that I can't hug my family and friends.
- Is there an optimal algorithm? (I hope not)

Answer (score 0):

## Shorten the numbers

These numbers are taking up far too many bytes on my computer. Create a function/program to shorten any number using only Alphanumeric characters as the output.

## Scoring

Scoring is based on `optimized-output`. Shortest number of characters produced for the following [randomly](https://www.calculator.net/random-number-generator.html?slower=999999999999&supper=99999999999999&ctype=1&s=5434&submit1=Generate) generated numbers (plus one special number with repetition) wins. Add the number of output characters output for the 5 test numbers together for total score.

- 94949267912781
- 75477115147709
- 79547324913976
- 12345678998765
- 11111122222222

The score of the non-optimized numbers = 70. (14 * 5)

## Sandbox questions

- does scoring make sense?
- should I include a sample script, output, or both?
- should I be more clear the answers should work on any number? (ie. "replacing each test number with one character is disallowed")?

Comment: Base conversion from base 10 to base-255?

Comment: As long as you're scoring on those five test numbers, the winning score is going to be the absolute smallest thing you haven't explicitly forbidden. Not allowing solutions to be tailored to those five is what we'd call a non-observable requirement, and considering how many different ways it could be approached I'm not sure how well a human could even really try to judge it. On the other hand, if you try to score it over the natural numbers, we just do base conversion. I feel like this can't work as an output optimization challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Match the entire lyrics of All-Star

The challenge is simple: create a program/function that, when given a string consisting of the entire lyrics to All-Star as they appear in [this paste](https://pastebin.com/s6u5tJre) (or not), output whether or not they are, in fact, the entire lyrics. The given string may be off by one of two characters, or something completely different, like [Moby Dick (approximately)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately). Output may consist of any of two values that map to `true` and `false`. They could be `0` and `1`, or `t` and `f`, or whatever you like so long as there are two *distinct* values. You can choose to print the output or return it (if you are a program or a function). This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: If the input string can be anything, is there anything one could do other than to compress the correct text and compare to it? If so, that would just be a generic compression challenge. One could check some cryptographic hash of the input, but there will exist collisions even if they are not practical to find.

Answer (score 0):

## Is this a simple cutting template?

A simple cutting template is a rectangle that can be recursively cut into smaller rectangles using only full-width cuts.

If you prefer a bottom-up description, then:

- A single rectangle is a simple cutting template with 0 cuts.
- Two simple cutting templates of the same width (or length) can be joined along their common side into a larger simple cutting template.

Input: A diagram of a rectangle subdivided into smaller rectangles, or a list of rectangles in some standard format, e.g. position and size.

Output: A truthy value if the diagram is a simple cutting template.

Note that if you take input as a diagram then all of the rectangle edges will use the same character, whearas in the truthy examples below, some of the edges have been replaced with digits to show a possible ordering of cuts while the falsy examples have the smallest portion of the input that is not a simple cutting template marked on them.

```
####2################
#   2               #
111111111111111111111
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #
111111111111111111111
#     2   2   2 4 4 #
3333332   2   2 4 4 #
# 4   2   2   2 4 4 #
# 45552   2   2 454 #
# 4 6 2   2   2 4 4 #
# 4 6 2   2   2 4 4 #
# 4 6 2   2   2 4 4 #
33333323332   2 4 4 #
#     2   2   2 4 4 #
#     23332   2 4 4 #
#     2   2   2 4 4 #
#     2   2   233333#
#     2   2   2     #
######2###2###2######
```

`-> Truthy`

```
##2#####4############
# 2     4           #
# 2333333333333333333
# 2         6     4 #
# 25555555555555554 #
# 2 6   6     8   4 #
# 2 6   67777777774 #
# 2 6   6         4 #
# 2 6   6         4 #
# 2 6   6         4 #
111111111111111111111
#               2   #
#               2333#
#               2   #
111111111111111111111
#   2             2 #
#   233333333333332 #
#   2 4 4     4   2 #
#   2 4 4555554   2 #
#   2 4 4     4   2 #
####2#############2##
```

`-> Truthy`

```
#####################
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #
111111111111111111111
# 2   4           2 #
# 2   4           2 #
# 2   4           2 #
# 23333333333333332 #
# 2     4   4 6 4 2 #
# 2     45554 6 4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4 6 4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4 6 4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4 6 4 2 #
# 2     4 6 45554 2 #
# 2     4 6 4   4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4   4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4   4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4   4 2 #
# 2     4 6 4   4 2 #
##2#####4#6#4###4#2##
```

`-> Truthy`

```
#####################
#               # # #
################# # #
#               # # #
#               # # #
#               # # #
?????????############
?     # ?     #     #
?     # ?     #     #
?     # ?     #     #
?     ##?     #     #
?     # ?     #     #
?###### ?############
?     # ? #       # #
?     # ? #       # #
?     # ? #       # #
?###### ?##       ###
? #   # ? #       # #
? ######? #       # #
? #     ? #       # #
?????????############
```

`-> Falsy`

```
?????????????????????
?     # # # # #     ?
?###### # # # #     ?
?     # # # # #     ?
?     # # # # ######?
?     # # # # #     ?
?###### # ##########?
? #   # # #         ?
? ##### # #         ?
? # # # # #         ?
? # # # # #         ?
? # # # # #         ?
? ####### #         ?
? #     # #         ?
? #     ############?
? #     #     #     ?
? #############     ?
? #     #     #     ?
? ##################?
? #         #       ?
?????????????????????
```

`-> Falsy`

```
#####################
#       #   #     # #
################### #
#                 # #
#####################
# #                 #
# ###################
# #   #             #
# ###################
# #   #     #       #
# ###################
# #                 #
# ???????????????????
# ?   #             ?
# ?   #             ?
# ?   #             ?
# ?   ##############?
# ?   #   #         ?
# ?########         ?
# ?       #         ?
##???????????????????
```

`-> Falsy`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: I think you should include an explicit definition: 'A *simple cutting template* is a rectangle that can be recursively cut into smaller rectangles using only full-width cuts.'

Comment: @Dingus Thanks for pointing that out, I think I must have accidentally edited it out by mistake when writing the sentence for the output.

Comment: I'd prefer one or two small examples with extra markings and then a list of copy-pasteable test cases.

Answer (score 0):

## Price this word [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

So, I'm going shopping in the **Word Market**™. There are shelves of words which I can buy around me, but I only have one dollar bills and the change machines at the market are broken. To add to the problem, there are words with... non-word characters in them. That's no good, I can't buy those... can you help me figure out which words I can buy and which I can't?

### Task

So, I can only buy words that consist of only alphabetical characters and are worth a dollar. To determine a word's value, you have to sum the letters in the word where `A = 1¢`, `B = 2¢`... to `Z = 26¢`. I'm too lazy to look at the output and judge whether it is equal to one  dollar (100 cents), so you'll need to return a specific value for words equal to a dollar (...or 100 cents) and a specific value for *not* equal to a dollar (I'm going to stop including this).

I'll also offer a bonus byte reduction: if your code returns whether the word is less than a dollar, equal to a dollar, greater than a dollar, or invalid (e.g. `<`, `=`, `>`, `x`), your score will be multiplied by 3/4.

**SANDBOX NOTE: Is this a balanced bonus value?**

### Examples

```
Word          Non-bonus value     Bonus value

a                  false               <
b                  false               <
printera           false               >
$word              false               x
printer            true                =
```

And here's a JavaScript snippet you can use if you want to check for non-bonus validity:

(it's also 52 bytes; you can use it by calling `f()`)

```
f=s=>([...s].map(x=>a+=parseInt(x,36)-9),a==100),a=0
```

Anyways, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, shortest answer in bytes wins (but I'll add shortest answers for esoteric *and* functional languages)... you get the idea.

Comment: In general, bonuses in code golf are [seen as something to avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/65425)

Comment: [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: This challenge doesn't seem interesting to me. We've already have plenty of challenges about summing up characters in a string, and having to determine whether a string contains non-word characters just seem like tacked on challenge that makes the whole thing more cumbersome.

Comment: What's a bit ironic about this is that after you posted this you went on to write a program that went through words in the English language and summed up their values depending on what character they were, [sharpness of a word](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18981/85381)

Comment: Never say I like the sharpness challenge either.  :P But I do think that that challenge is a bit more interesting, due to the somewhat arbitrary mapping of letter to values. Yours just straight up uses the vanilla alphabetical order.

Comment: You do have a point; in Jelly or 05AB1E there's probably a builtin that would sum up a string based on values like I want people to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Magic card trick: Hide information by flipping cards

<sub>(This is inspired by a series of questions on puzzles.stackexchange.com:
[10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52228/is-this-10-card-magic-trick-possible),
[8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52322/magicians-hide-and-seek-with-8-cards),
[7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89851/the-flippin-magicians-7-card-grand-finale))</sub>

Fix two integers *m* and *u*. Your task is to perform the following magic trick:

- A Magician brings a pack of *m* distinct cards, and leaves the room.
- In their absence, a volunteer from the audience shuffles the deck and arranges all cards in a line, in any order they want.
- Still in the absence of the magician, their assistant flips *u* cards. On the table are the n cards, still in the order chosen by the volunteers, but *u* are face down, leaving only *m*−*u* cards face up.
- The magician returns, and from the order of the cards alone, knows each card.

#### Input:

*m* - number of cards.

*u* - number of cards to flip face down.

- You may assume 0 < *u* < *m*.

#### Output, if the trick is possible for *m* and *u*:

*f* - an mapping assigning to each sequence the order the assistant will create by flipping cards.

- If the trick is to work, this mapping must be bijective.
- Use the integers 1...*m* (or 0...*m*−1), or single letters as card values.
- Use any meaningful way to express *f*: a hash maps, a table, a function.
- Use a fixed placeholder for any face-down cards.

#### Output, if the trick is impossible for given values of *m* and *u*

This case should be indicated in a meaningful way.

#### Example output (*m*=3, *u*=1):

Using the digits `0`, `1`, and `2` as cards, and `_` for their flipside:

```
012 01_
021 0_1
102 _02
120 12_
201 2_1
210 _10
```

<sub>(For these values of *m* and *u*, this isn't very impressive as a magic trick, of course.)</sub>

#### Example output (*m*=4, *u*=2):

Using `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` for the cards and `0` for their flipside, and a JSON representation:

```
{"1234":"0034","1243":"0043","1324":"0024","1342":"0042","1423":"0023","1432":"0032",
"2134":"0104","2143":"0103","2314":"0014","2341":"0041","2413":"0013","2431":"0031",
"3124":"0120","3142":"0102","3214":"0204","3241":"0201","3412":"0012","3421":"0021",
"4123":"4003","4132":"0130","4213":"0203","4231":"0230","4312":"0302","4321":"0301"}
```

<sub>This is correct because as required, the keys are all permutations of `1234`, each value has two cards face-down and the other cards match the original sequence, and each value appears only once.</sub>

### Scoring

This is code-golf. Shortest solution wins.

Comment: I think I should not allow all that input/output flexibility and require some fixed format. For example: input is *u* and a string whose (unique) characters are the decks. Require `_`  as placeholder. Require a fixed table format.

Comment: There were some clarity issues I had while reading this, but as is I think this has a much bigger problem. It seems very likely to me that outputs for large `m` will be prohibitively difficult to verify, given the complexity of the proofs from the related puzzling challenges. There are many ways you could approach this, like upper bounding `m`, making this a [tag:test-battery], or making a [tag:code-challenge] where the goal is to find the maximum `u` for the highest `m`. There are probably other ways to handle this, so these are just some starting ideas. Thanks for using the sandbox!

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback @FryAmTheEggman. The proofs from the linked puzzles are long because they're reasoning & looking for insight. To just verify the list, two steps are sufficient: verify that *f*(*x*) is obtained from *x* by replacing *u* symbols with `_`, and that *f* is a bijection and defined for all permutations. [Non-golfed solution including full tests](https://pastebin.com/Fnz5A4W4) . The output will still be huge, no chance of cursory manual verification. I didn't know about alternatives to code-golf, actually! I'll be looking into these.

Comment: No problem! I do want to clarify though - I was aware of the ability to prove by exhaustion when I posted my first comment. However, I did base my assessment of it being a true problem around you not wanting a completely naive brute force search through each strategy, which I see now wasn't correct, so if you are fine with that then there isn't really a problem. But of course, if you want anything besides those solutions I'd recommend looking into what I suggested, or asking in our chat room for other people's points of view.

Answer (score 0):

### Partition distance [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Quoting Anush:

> I am very glad to provide a service to fill in the terrible gap in edit distance questions which codegolf.se has had. When there are as many edit distance questions as quine questions my job will be done.

--[Anush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/202974/code-golf-edit-distance-2#comment481733_202974)

### Task

Given a binary string consisting only of `0`'s and `1`'s, partition the binary string (divide the string into consecutive substrings), and determine the *minimal* edit distance in order to transform one piece into another, left to right. You need to output the sum of the edit distances between consecutive blocks.

### Example

I'm going to make a reference implementation to find the optimal partitions. But that's after I dump all my ideas, though.

```
011010110111

We partition the string like this:
[011][010][110][111]

And then find the cumultative edit distance between each 2 pairs of partitioned strings:
[1 1 1]

Then, we sum the list of partitions.
[3]

So 3 is a possible output for this binary string. However, you need to find the minimum edit distance, so this might not be the correct answer.
```

### Another example

```
001001010

We partition this string:
[001][001][010]

And then find the mimimal edit distance between each piece.
[0 1]

Therefore, our (non-optimal?) output for 001001010 is 1 ([0 1] summed).
```

### Rules

- The edit distance between two strings is the minimum number of single character insertions, deletions and substitutions needed to transform one string into the other.
- The input is guaranteed to have at least length 3.
- The pieces of your partition don't have to be the same length.

Comment: What do you mean by "partition the input string"? Can I choose any partition I want as long as it's not all singletons or the entire thing? Or do I have to find one that's optimal in some sense? Why is the all-singletons case disallowed? Is the output the sum of the edit distances between consecutive blocks? From the examples I guess it is but you should say it explicitly.

Comment: @Zgarb "partition the input string" means divide the input string into (not necessarily equal) consecutive substrings. You need to find one that's optimal, I've emphasized that. I allowed the all-singleton case; I specified that the output is the edit distance sum between consecutive blocks explicitly.

Comment: It should still be made clearer that the output is the minimum over all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate of [Find the minimum edit distance between two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/find-the-minimum-edit-distance-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 0):

## Mobile games money representation

In many mobile clicker games where the player is usually required to tap on the screen to make money (in order to buy upgrades for you to generate money faster), it gets to a point in the game that the money made per second is so big that if represented in its "normal" form, it would clutter the mobile screen. Imagine showing the user that they are making \$1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000\$ per second in a small mobile phone screen!

From my experience as a regular player of these type of games, I have noticed that most of them represent bigger numbers by using letters. If the number of money per second is a number less than \$10,000,000\$ then print the number as is. Otherwise, if the number is in the millions (but \$ \geq 10,000,000\$), for example  \$ 102,000,000\$ it should print \$102M\$. If it is in the billions, it should print \$102B\$. You should use \$T\$ for trillion and \$Q\$ for quadrillion.

As you can notice, the next would be quintillion which would also use the letter \$Q\$ if followed the pattern. Instead of following this pattern which can be confusing at one point, game developers usually start a new pattern: Quintillion is used with the suffix \$AA\$, sextillion is \$AB\$, septillion is \$AC\$ and so on.

Notice that this pattern would go until \$AZ\$ and if the player is making more money than that, it would start from \$BA\$, \$BB\$, ..., \$BZ\$, ...,\$ZA\$, \$ZB\$, ... , \$ZZ\$ which for our problem we will assume is the limit one player can make per second.

## Task

Given an integer \$x\$ where \$0 \lt x \leq 999\$ and a natural number \$y\$ where \$y \gt 0\$ representing the number of zeroes the number has, output the number in a "mobile game money representation" as described above.

## Observations

- The number of zeroes that \$y\$ represent **does not** include the possible zeroes \$x\$ might have! Example: if \$x = 100\$ and \$y = 6\$, you should output \$100M\$ and not \$1,000,000\$

## Test Cases (x, y --> game money representation)

```
100,  6 --> 100M
100,  5 --> 10M 
100,  4 --> 1000000
1,   12 --> 1T
10,  12 --> 10T
100, 12 --> 100T
1,   18 --> 1AA
10,  18 --> 10AA
100, 18 --> 100AA
# To be added...
```

## Meta questions

1. Is this a duplicate? I have looked around but didn't find anything similar.
2. Is the wording confusing? I'm open to recommendations!
3. I haven't written a program yet so the test cases might be wrong (I'll add more later).
4. Pretty much any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it needs some test cases with decimal points, e.g. `123, 17 -> 12.3AA`.

Comment: Shouldn't 100, 4 become 1M?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum In these games, when the number is small enough (as I said in the second paragraph), if the number is less than 10 million, then it is printed in its "normal" form. The abreviations starts after 10 million.

Comment: Suggest cases where \$y\$ don't just go the `AA`

Comment: Thanks all, I'm pretty busy lately unfortunately. Whenever I get the time I'll try to update the challenge

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the pointiness, sharpness and smoothness of a letter [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

<sup>Inspired by [Determine the sharpness of a word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205533/determine-the-sharpness-of-a-word).</sup>
You are given an uppercase letter of the English alphabet as input. You have to compute (and output) its pointiness, sharpness and smoothness. Since it is difficult to define these objectively, here's a table of the outputs:

```
            A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
pointiness: 2 0 2 0 3 3 2 4 4 2 4 2 2 2 0 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 4 3 2
sharpness:  1 2 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 3 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 2
smoothness: 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Transposed version (first lists the letter, then the pointiness, then the sharpness and then the smoothness)  <sup><sup>(like a true CGCC user, I transposed it with Jelly and added spacing with Retina)</sup></sup>:

```
A 2 1 0
B 0 2 2
C 2 0 1
D 0 2 1
E 3 2 0
F 3 1 0
G 2 1 1
H 4 0 0
I 4 0 0
J 2 1 1
K 4 0 0
L 2 1 0
M 2 3 0
N 2 2 0
O 0 0 1
P 1 1 1
Q 1 0 1
R 2 1 1
S 2 0 2
T 3 0 0
U 2 0 1
V 2 1 0
W 2 3 0
X 4 0 0
Y 3 0 0
Z 2 2 0
```

Bonus imaginary internet points if you find a language where this is built-in.

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

## Sandbox stuff

- Is this not a duplicate?
- Is the table computed correctly? (the only ones that don't seem certain with the current font are `I`'s pointiness, `G`'s sharpness and `S`'s smoothness)

Comment: After fiddling about a bit, I think this should probably have enough patterns that mindlessly compressing the numbers won't be the best strategy. Still, I could be wrong, but [here](https://tio.run/##DYdBCoQwDADv@49CKy5tTNLEg0/wFx70Eot0D/v6GgZmmPbv5204hm1IjkhhES0ASAyraPUHBEQtqIzqJRKCnCtMU1zL936OeFn79ZhSChU@7bmsR8t54dnNwRM4jbG/) is what I used to see roughly how long such an approach would be (I encoded each set of values to a base 5 number, then in turn encoded that list of numbers into a base 61 number). Separately, you probably want to include the data in a more copy-pastable way.

Answer (score 0):

### ax + by, a & b are coprime [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

### Backstory

> A doctor in Berlin, after analyzing his medical history, has realized that all of the results of his integral measurement results can be represented in the form of \$23x+28y\$, where \$x\$ and \$y\$ are integers.

However, he could have extended his theory. \$23\$ and \$28\$ can be replaced by any two coprime numbers, and this theory would still hold. (He didn't have time to write his theory in a paper, that's quite awful.)

### Task

Without examples, I'll *never* be convinced that this nonsensical theory holds!

Given \$the\ output\ of\ (ax+by)\$ (let's call it \$z\$), \$x\$, and \$y\$, find the smallest pair of \$(a,\ b)\$ that makes \$ax + by = z\$ true.

### Example cases

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the factorial, on both sides of 0

Why, why, why do factorials stop at zero? (Yes there are actual reasons). Make a factorial function (or full program) that doesn't stop at zero!

Your code-golfed program should, given an non-zero integer `n` (can be positive or negative, the rule still applies), find the product of the range `n to -n` excluding 0.

[Graph that at least works for positive numbers](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oxswtak72k)

#### Sample IO

```sql
 Input          | Output
----------------|------------
0               | 1 (product of 0 and -0 without 0 / empty product)
2               | 4 (2*1*-1*-2)
3               | -36 (3*2*1*-1*-2*-3)
4               | 576 (4*3*2*1*-1*-2*-3*-4)
-4              | 576
```

Probably not a duplicate, but it might not be that much of a challenge.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial)

Comment: Would the input always be positive? Is n=0 a possible input?

Comment: @Bubbler For now I'll say 0 is undefined, might change it later before posting if I have a good idea.

Comment: As it is, isn't this always the factorial of the absolute value of the input squared, then made negative if the input is odd? - except in the edge case for zero? The sign of the input doesn't really appear to matter, which is an odd feeling.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes, see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9lghv8fiv1) graph of the values. Is that a bad thing? Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: "downvotes mean nothing but rudeness" - I downvoted this because I do not think "compute \$|n|!^2 \cdot (-1)^n\$" is a good challenge. I can't see how disagreement is rude. The requirements here seem completely arbitrary to me. This will result in the exact same approaches as were used in the factorial challenge.

Comment: I think it is a bad thing in that it becomes dangerously close to a dupe of the factorial problem. I probably wouldn't hammer it immediately, but if most of the responses basically worked for both or many others had the same concern I'd probably close it. I'm not sure of a good way to modify this to be better, so unfortunately I don't have any suggestions at the moment. I will let you know if something occurs to me.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I wouldn't consider it a dupe but I wouldn't consider it a good question after all based off of what my pronoun is monicareinstate said.

Comment: If you consider 0 as a valid input, I suggest that its expected output be 1, which corresponds to the empty product ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)).

Comment: For the interesting-ness, I believe it can be interesting in at least some languages (which IMHO justifies the value of having such a challenge). FWIW, I have two J solutions of equal length, one using the factorial built-in `!` and the other not using it.

Comment: I'd likewise close this as a duplicate, but I'm known for having much broader standards than the rest of the community about what questions are closeworthy, so make of that what you will.

Comment: I'll just abandon this, but if @Bubbler wants to post it, they can.

Answer (score 0):

## Default Lightning Strike

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Introduction:

Inspired by this reddit question: [ELI5: Why does lightning travel in a zig-zag manner rather than a straight line?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/hf6ybh/eli5_why_does_lightning_travel_in_a_zigzag_manner/)

Although it's more complex than this, in general multiple lightning paths will randomly check its immediate surrounding for the direction with least resistance (based on air pressure, temperature, composure, humility, etc.) and travel in that direction. As soon as one of the paths reaches the ground, that entire path has the least resistance and most (although not all) of the ions will accumulate in that path, causing the lightning flash and thunder.
[Here a slow-mo video of a lightning strike to get an idea.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dukkO7c2eUE)

### Challenge:

**Input:** An integer \$h\geq3\$ and an integer \$1\leq p\leq\left\lfloor\frac{h}{2}\right\rfloor\$

**Output:** Each step of the ASCII animation of a [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) lightning strike, with a cloud to earth height of \$h\$ and *up to* \$p\$ paths

We start with a lightning ion at the cloud, with a lowercase letter of your own choosing (i.e. `b`). This ion will travel in a random direction (horizontally, vertically, or (anti-)diagonally), except where this path itself comes from. Every 'tick' it also has a 20% chance of branching out into two paths, as long as we haven't reached \$p\$ paths yet. Each of these paths will behave the same.
As soon as any path hits the ground based on the height \$h\$, all letters of that particular path will become uppercase, and in the final 'tick' after that, only this uppercase path will remain.

### Challenge rules:

- Paths can intersect with other paths
- Paths can travel upwards beyond the height of our starting point
- Output can be in any reasonable format. Could be a list of multi-line strings for each 'tick'. Could be a list of character-matrices for each 'tick'. Could be pretty-printed to STDOUT (with clear non-whitespace separation between each 'tick' - i.e. a single character like a comma or semi-colon, or a line of `---` or `___`)
- Trailing spaces for each line of a tick are optional (leading as well, as long as the lightning bolts are still correct)
- If multiple paths strike the ground in the same 'tick', only the first one of those two (or more) paths will become the lightning strike. The order in which paths are created are therefore important, so keep that in mind.

### Examples:

This may all sound pretty vague, so here a couple of examples:
(I've added trailing spaces for each step with spaces, but you don't necessarily have to do so as mentioned in the challenge rules.)

**Example 1:** \$h=3, p=1\$

```
Tick 1:
"b"
" "
" "
Tick 2 (random direction: right):
"bb"
"  "
"  "
Tick 3 (random direction: up-left):
"b "
"bb"
"  "
"  "
Tick 4 (random direction: down-left):
" b "
"bbb"
"   "
"   "
Tick 5 (random direction: down):
" b "
"bbb"
"b  "
"   "
Tick 6 (random direction: up-right):
Note that this overlaps with a previous step in this path, which is fine.
" b "
"bbb"
"b  "
"   "
Tick 7 (random direction: down-right):
" b "
"bbb"
"b b"
"   "
Tick 8 (random direction: down):
" b "
"bbb"
"b b"
"  b"
Tick 9 (lightning strike):
" B "
"BBB"
"B B"
"  B"
Tick 10 (extra tick to remove all other paths, although there are none right now):
" B "
"BBB"
"B B"
"  B"
```

**Example 2:** \$h=5, p=2\$

```
Tick 1:
"b"
" "
" "
" "
" "
Tick 2 (random direction: down-left):
" b"
"b "
"  "
"  "
"  "
Tick 3 (random direction: down-left):
"  b"
" b "
"b  "
"   "
"   "
Tick 4 (random direction: right):
"  b"
" b "
"bb "
"   "
"   "
Tick 5 (random 20% path split; random direction 1: top-right, random direction 2: right):
"  b"
" bb"
"bbb"
"   "
"   "
Tick 6 (random direction 1: top-left, random direction 2: down):
" bb"
" bb"
"bbb"
"  b"
"   "
Tick 7 (random direction 1: left, random direction 2: down-right):
"bbb "
" bb "
"bbb "
"  b "
"   b"
Tick 8 (lightning strike of path 2):
"bbB "
" Bb "
"BBB "
"  B "
"   B"
Tick 9 (extra tick to remove all the other paths, which is path 1 in this case):
"  B "
" B  "
"BBB "
"  B "
"   B"
```

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

---

## *Sandbox Questions:*

- *Should I perhaps use a different letter of the alphabet per path?*

  - If yes: what would happen when different letter-paths overlap? I assume the top one will be visible per 'tick', but if lightning is struck it should still change it to the underlying letter as uppercase. In either case, you'll have to keep track of each individual path and uppercase only the one that struck the ground (first).
- Any additional rules or things that are unclear?
- An additional relevant tag?
- More examples with more paths and/or larger height?
- A different path percentage instead of hard-coded \$\frac{1}{5}\$ / 20%.

Answer (score 0):

## Sort numbers using as few distinct bytes as possible

### Task

Write an algorithm that takes as input an ordered list ([array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), etc...) of numbers and outputs an ordered list containing the same numbers sorted by their value (ascending or descending).

The numbers may be represented using the most convenient format to you, with the only restriction that there must be a way to encode 256 distinct numbers. You are not allowed to use built-in sorting functions/algorithms.

### Scoring criteria

Let \$c\$ be the number of distinct bytes in your code* and let \$s\$ be the number of bytes in your code*.
*Or its UTF-8 representation

The score is equal to \$c^2 + s\$. The answer with the lowest score wins!

**Examples** (imagine these are sorting algorithms):

- `ababccbaacbabcba` → \$c=3, s=16, score=25\$
- `aAbcd€f` → \$c=9, s=9, score=90\$
- bytes `16 ee 3c 79 ee` → \$c=4, s=5, score=21\$

---

I'm open to suggestions, especially about the score formula.

Comment: I see that this is your first attempt at writing a challenge. Thank you so much for using the sandbox!

Comment: Please note that it is very hard to write good challenges [that restrict solutions from certain things](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/43319). This is because it is hard to define exactly what is prohibited in every language, and it is also hard to determine *if* any prohibited feature was used.

Comment: @Adám So how should I prevent trivial answers? Maybe "built-in sorting functions/algorithms" is a bit vague.

Comment: We don't prevent trivial answers in most cases. Btw, if I accept plain numbers as input, may I assume the input is a list of integers between 0 and 255 inclusive?

Comment: How about this: "You are not allowed to use any built-in function/command that can take an ordered container and output the sorted result. Anything else is OK."

Comment: I think a good solution would be to allow built-in solutions, but to compile (in advance, so that it can be posted very quickly, probably via the "answer your own question" feature) a community wiki answer listing trivial 1-byte solutions.

Comment: @Bubbler Would still be unclear if J's `/:~` or `/:]` were allowed or not.

Comment: @D.Pardal Why do you want to prevent trivial answers?

Comment: I wanted to prevent built-in functions because otherwise most answers would be exactly the same as the ones from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list). Maybe the easiest way to solve this would be to replace the task of sorting an array with another.

Comment: Yes. Banning built-in has long been considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

## [Distributive on myself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206904/distributive-on-myself) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 0):

## Fix mispellings [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Wikipedia has a [list of common misspellings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings), and there is also a machine-readable version!

Your challenge is to input a string and fix the mispellings in it.

The parituclar list we'll be using is https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines&oldid=962756669#The_Machine-Readable_List. Note that even if the list changes, you must use this version. Here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/j03aL98d.

Each line in the list is in the format `INPUT->OUTPUT1, OUTPUT2, OUTPUT3, ...` (of course, there may be more or less possible outputs, or even just one). That means that for input `INPUT` you must output exactly one of the possible outputs `OUTPUT...`.

This is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

## Sandbox stuff

Should I add more misspellings to the post, or should I remove them?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200761/46076)

Comment: @pppery While the idea is probably related, I don't think the solutions would be related at all.

Comment: What is the input format? A plain English sentence (so we need to handle spaces, punctuation, capitalization), or is a list of words acceptable? How should capitalization be handled (some entries look like `Tolkein->Tolkien` and `UnitesStates->UnitedStates`; given `unkown->unknown`, what is the expected output of `unkown`, `Unkown`, `UNKown`, `Tolkein`, `tolkein`, `TOLKEIN`)?

Comment: @Bubbler The input is a single entry in the list (the part before ->, of course). You do not need to handle capitalization ("tOLKEIN" is not "Tolkein"). (will clarify later).

Answer (score 0):

### Overlap characters [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Put all the characters of a given list, following the order, in a sequence of bits keeping it as small as possible.

**Rules**

- Write the bits of each character on a line.
- You can overlap bits if they are equal.
- You cannot change already written bits.
- Extend the line, in both directions, if not all the bits fit in.
- Always try to extend as less as possible.

**Example**

```
input :['a','&','1','.']
     0110 0001  // a
0010 0110      // &
           001 1000 1     // 1
                 00 1011 10 // .
                 
output :0010011000011000101110

input : "&1a."

       0010 0110      // &
          0 0110 001     // 1
0 1100 001  // a
                 0010 1110 // .
                 
output : 011000010011000101110
```

**I/O rules**

- input can be any sequence of single byte elements.
- output the resulting sequence of bits in any convenient method, no extraneous bits allowed (0 or 1)

Answer (score 0):

## Crazy Blazin' DOM Injection

I was instructed to post this code golf challenge here for recommendations on how to modify the challenge.

I'd like to tag it.

fastest-code grid and browser , but I don't know how to do that here.

Code golf challenge listed below.

## Introduction

This problem is a challenge that has to do with DOM manipulation at scale and overcoming some issues that may be inherent in dealing with the DOM.

- This challenge is interesting because limitations push us to think through things differently and lean on the strengths of languages different than what we usually use.
- I created this challenge myself based on a real world problem I ran into myself (details can be provided if needed). If this challenge has any relation to a differently know problem, those similarities are coincidental.

This challenge will be scored based on fastest execution and fastest algorithm. A multiplier will be given for completing the challege at [easy](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/1000-cells.html), [medium](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/10000-cells.html), and [hard](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/100000-cells.html) difficulties.

## Challenge

You must render one of the challenge levels in a web browser:

- [easy](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/1000-cells.html)
- [medium](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/10000-cells.html)
- [hard](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/100000-cells.html)

Through any means available to you interacting through a web browser in code you need to complete the following:

1. Get each table displayed and add a class `table-n` to each table where `n` is a zero based index of order of the table on the screen. If a table is nested within a table the parent would be N and the child would be N+1 with the next table being N+2.
2. Get each row displayed in each table and add a class of `table-n-row-r` where `r` is a zero based index of rows in the table represented by `table-n`.
3. Get each cell displayed in each table and add a class of `table-n-row-r-cell-c` where `c` is a zero based index of cells in a row represented by `table-n-row-r`.

At the end of the challenge the web page should still be able to be interacted through in the browser, and a call to `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` should return one and only one cell from the DOM.

Any method available to you as valid as long as:

1. Access to one of the difficulty levels has been done through a web browser
2. The URL of the browser and the page displayed doesn't change
3. A call to `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` returns only one element

## Output Examples

For this example we're using the [easy](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/1000-cells.html) level as input.

The abbreviated output in the DOM should be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Code Golf Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table-0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-0-row-0">
                <th class="table-0-row-0-cell-0">1</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-0-row-1">
                <td class="table-0-row-1-cell-0">11</td>
                <td class="table-0-row-1-cell-1">12</td>
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

There are only `<td>` and `<th>` elements used as cell elements for the challenge.

As long as `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` returns an element with this class. We're good to go.

## Qualifying Entries

All entries that qualify need to have an execution speed of under 40 seconds for any difficulty level.

Timing starts when your algorithm starts, but after the page has loaded completely as all elements must be available (the browser spinner has stopped spinning).

Calculate the runtime for your method by calling `performance.now()` before and and after your injection method, and subtracting the first from the second as in the example below.

```
let t0 = performance.now();
doSomething()   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 
let t1 = performance.now();
let totalTime = t1 - t0;
```

The medium and hard difficulty levels will have their execution time multiplied by `0.50` and `0.25` respectively. None the less, an execution time of less than 40 seconds is needed to qualify. So if the execution time on the medium difficulty was 41 seconds before the multiplier, it does not qualify.

## Winner

The winner will be determined by the shortest execution time for dynamic injection of these classes and where `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` can still be executed against the browser console and return an element where `n`, `r`, and `c` are replaced with indexes.

Comment: Do you mean that all entries should be written as a JS function so that it can be run inside the browser console? Which browser(s) will you be using to time it (since different browsers may have different support of JS features and the engine optimized in different ways)?

Comment: "scored based on fastest execution and fastest algorithm" is ambiguous, because fastest execution means that a constant factor in the algorithm is important, while fastest algorithm is not. I think you mean simply "fastest execution", since it seems hard to use a big-O notation in this task (should it be a function of table size or entire document size?).

Comment: All entries should be written as a JS function (I think that's the only way to achieve it). However, if there are other ways to achieve this they are welcome, but it still needs to be an active webpage pulled from the internet. So, pulling via wget or curl and manipulating it locally in something like jelly is out of the question unless Jelly can interact with the browser. We can standardize on chrome 83.0.1.x for the web browser, so that it's exactly the same for all.

Comment: It should only be fastest execution then. Let's go with that.

Comment: Also, if a submission works for all of easy/medium/hard, how is it scored? I guess the minimum of (easy time), (medium time / 2), (hard time / 4)?

Comment: If a submission works for all level (qualifies at all levels) it gets scored at the hardest level it qualifies for.

Comment: That sounds like unnecessarily penalizing possibly good submissions because it might run blazing fast on easy but more than 4x slower on hard, giving it a worse score.

Comment: I can agree with that. How do you suggest we even that out?

Comment: Personally, I think it is better to do away with the different difficulty levels. They aren't exactly the same as [bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/31625) but most of the arguments for why we don't like bonuses apply to these difficulties, too.

Comment: I think this will work: "The submission that handles the highest difficulty within 40 seconds wins, ties broken by the time taken to complete for that test case." If the first part of the sentence is confusing, I mean "a submission that handles hard is better than one that can't".

Comment: I'll get rid of the difficulty levels.

Comment: Actually, Bubbler, what you said makes sense. I'll state it like you said and get rid of the bonus.

Comment: Still getting downvotes on the challenge. I don't know the reason why. Implemented the changes we discussed, but I guess it still doesn't meet standards? 
(^-^;)

Answer (score 0):

## How wide is this string?

Given a unicode string in any standard encoding of choice, determine how many columns wide it is.

To keep this challenge relatively simple, use the following rules for character widths:

- Tab characters align to the nearest multiple-of-8 column
- CJK characters are 2 columns wide.

  - For the purposes of this challenge, you may assume all characters in [Unicode Planes 2 and 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) (U+20000-3FFFF), plus codepoints U+3400-9FFF are CJK characters.
  - CJK characters outside these ranges may be treated as either 1 or 2 columns wide.
- Combining diacritics (U+0300-036F), control characters (U+00-1F, U+7F-9F), and the zero-width space (U+200B) are all 0 columns wide.

  - All other officially zero-width characters may be treated as either 1 or 0 columns wide.
- You may assume that there are no newlines or carriage returns.
- You do not need to handle escape sequences.
- You may assume all other characters are 1 column wide.

  - For any character the standard says has a specific width, you may use that width instead.

Shortest code wins.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

Answer (score 0):

## Tumbling 2x2 in a Matrix

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

### Challenge:

**Input:** A rectangular integer matrix that's at least 2x2 in size.
**Output:** A 2D integer array, of the result after the top-left 2x2 block has tumbled down.

For example: Let's say we have the following 3x5 matrix as input:

```
[[ 4, 7,12],
 [11, 2, 5],
 [ 7, 3,15],
 [21,10, 1],
 [12, 6, 6]]
```

The 2x2 block is `[[4,7],[11,2]]`, which will act as if it was tumbling down from a stairs (in a top-left to bottom-right direction). Here this process step-by-step:

```
[[ 4, 7,  ],
 [11, 2,  ],
 [--,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ]]

[[  ,  , 4],
 [  ,11, 7],
 [--, 2,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ]]

[[  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,11, 4],
 [--, 2, 7],
 [  ,--,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ]]

[[  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ,11],
 [--,  , 2, 4],
 [  ,--, 7],
 [  ,  ,  ]]

[[  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [--,  , 2,11],
 [  ,--, 7, 4],
 [  ,  ,--]]

[[  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [--,  ,  ,  , 2],
 [  ,--,  , 7,11],
 [  ,  ,--, 4]]

[[  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [--,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [  ,--,  , 7, 2],
 [  ,  ,--, 4,11]]
```

Doing so, it will add it's values to the other cells in its path. So here is the same step-by-step process with the other numbers added in the cells:

```
[[ 4, 7,12],
 [11, 2, 5],
 [ 7, 3,15],
 [21,10, 1],
 [12, 6, 6]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,12],
 [ 7, 5,15],
 [21,10, 1],
 [12, 6, 6]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16],  // Note that the 13 and 5 remain the same, because the cells of the tumbling
 [ 7, 5,22],  // block haven't moved from the previous to this step
 [21,10, 1],
 [12, 6, 6]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16,11],
 [ 7, 5,24, 4],
 [21,10, 8],
 [12, 6, 6]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16,11],
 [ 7, 5,24,15],  // Note that the 24 and 8 remain the same, because the cells of the tumbling
 [21,10, 8, 4],  // block haven't moved from the previous to this step
 [12, 6, 6]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16,11],
 [ 7, 5,24,15, 2],
 [21,10, 8,11,11],
 [12, 6, 6, 4]]

[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16,11],
 [ 7, 5,24,15, 2],
 [21,10, 8,11,13],  // Note that the 11 and 4 remain the same, because the cells of the tumbling
 [12, 6, 6, 4,11]]  // block haven't moved from the previous to this step
```

### Challenge rules:

- I/O is flexible. You may take the input as integer-matrix, integer list with loose dimension-inputs, as a list of strings, etc. Output can modify the original input, return a new matrix, print space/newline delimiter to STDOUT, etc.
- You may optionally take the dimensions as additional input.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test case:

```
Input:
[[ 4, 7,12],
 [11, 2, 5],
 [ 7, 3,15],
 [21,10, 1],
 [12, 6, 6]]
Output:
[[ 4, 7,16],
 [11,13,16,11],
 [ 7, 5,24,15, 2],
 [21,10, 8,11,13],
 [12, 6, 6, 4,11]]
```

*TODO: More to come.*

---

## *Sandbox questions:*

*I might change the tumbling process a bit later on, since I'm not too happy about the current one. I still want the tumbling 2x2 down the matrix, but I might make the way the other values changes a bit different. This is just an initial idea.*

- *Any missing tags?*
- *Any missing rules?*
- *Any suggestions on how to change the output without changing the core part of the tumbling top-left 2x2 block?*
- *Any suggested test cases?*

Answer (score 0):

## \$d\times n\$ dimensional word matrices [WIP]

Given two positive integers \$n\$ and \$d\$, and a list of words \$a\$, produce a \$d\$-dimensional matrix \$m\$ with each dimension having length \$n\$, filled with letters, that contains the words from \$a\$ placed such that they form a directly adjacent contiguous path through the dimensions.

For example, given \$d = 1\$, \$n = 3\$ and \$a = \$`['cat']` output one of:

```
cat
```

or

```
tac
```

Given \$d = 2\$, \$n = 3\$ and \$a = \$`['cat', 'hat', 'mat']` output something similar to:

```
cat
hat
mat
```

Given \$d = 3\$, \$n = 3\$ and \$a = \$`['low', 'complexity']` output something similar to:

```
coq
igw
typ

kmc
xeo
buf

kpr
dll
scm
```

or, if it's easier to visualise in an array structure:

```
[
  [
    ['c', 'o', 'q'],
    ['i', 'g', 'w'],
    ['t', 'y', 'p'],
  ],
  [
    ['k', 'm', 'c'],
    ['x', 'e', 'o'],
    ['b', 'u', 'f'],
  ],
  [
    ['k', 'p', 'r'],
    ['d', 'l', 'l'],
    ['s', 'c', 'm'],
  ],
]
```

Which contains `low` at nested indices \$m[2][1][2]\$, \$m[1][1][2]\$, \$m[0][1][2]\$ and `complexity` at \$m[0][0][0]\$, \$m[0][0][1]\$, \$m[1][0][1]\$, \$m[2][0][1]\$, \$m[2][1][1]\$, \$m[1][1][1]\$, \$m[1][1][0]\$, \$m[0][1][0]\$, \$m[0][2][0]\$, \$m[0][2][1]\$.

*I'd like to add some more complicated examples beyond three dimensions here.*

### Test Cases

**TODO**

### Rules

- Unused spaces should be filled with randomly selected letters.
- There will always be enough space in the dimensions provided to allow the words to be added without re-using letters.
- There is no requirement to ensure the words don't also appear elsewhere in the grid, so for example if the filler letters happen to spell one of the provided words, that is acceptable.

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Questions for meta

- This seems fun to me, any thoughts?
- Is it too easy/hard?
- Any other tags that are relevant?
- As a follow up, I'd like to have a nested matrix provided and have programs solve it - but that might be better as a fastest-code challenge - is this a reasonable precursor?

Comment: Is `d^n` large enough to contain all the words without sharing letters?

Comment: Yeah, you won't have to be concerned with that, I'll add that to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

## Trapping a Jogger

A person starts jogging to the right from his house on a busy street.

```
t=0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - G - - - G
>
```

He travels 1 hectometer every minute, so he is 11 hectometers away from his house after 11 minutes:

```
t=11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - R - - R - - - G
                      >
```

Since this is a busy street, there are walking signals that occasionally turn red. In this example, the signals at `5`, `8`, and `12` units from home alternate colors every `2`, `10`, and `4` minutes (this would not be a fun road to drive on). The signals are red (signal stop ✋) for the same duration that they are green (signal go ).

Our jogger doesn't want to wait long, so he instantly turns around when he reaches a stoplight that is red, even if it will turn green within the next minute.

```
t=12
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - R - - - R
                        >
```

```
t=12.001
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - R - - - R
                        <
```

```
t=13
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - R - - - R
                      <
```

This can cause the jogger to reverse direction again, making for a potentially long outing.

```
t=16
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - R - - - G
                <
```

```
t=16.001
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C
⌂ - - - - G - - R - - - G
                >
```

View the rest of the sequence using a [visualizer](https://tio.run/##bVFNa8MwDL37V4jAsN24bZxtMEqy6@67BlNC7a4enWMSj22MXXber9wfyeSkHylMYGFL8nt6kv8Iu8Zd971vOiihuhV3QuaKBPtihkAuZCZuFCEBXxnxg9foU0mINluw3bo1mnkBga8IoLUmvLYOwnI5oFQIvbBOm3fmubrKx2@@tS6su1AHwzaHj0OMbWkoP0O6@aJ8EqW/P99AIcVDF8@NdawastHowyOtDn1YEbgCi32BdRBVmX1ngM7pqXzbtGO2rd2TYVJgVTWXKpUjoeJT4gSSWT7zyJwU90mly1KqaZ4TMtWScfK2s3sDOC8cFSBXBgV4KEo48IxiA6QlyBEoXvUZ8wwVQ6jFH7XUTv8z8GhxJXN9el7gLLJMHttkiek2tcf@cDerJIL0/R8).

### Task

Given the cycle intervals and positions of a list of streetlights, determine the time until the jogger returns to his house (at distance 0) or runs to the right of the rightmost streetlight.

The streetlights at time `t=0` will all have just turned green.

The `n` cycle intervals shall all be integers at least `2`. The `n` positions of the streetlights may be taken as either (sorted) absolute distances from home or the distance from that streetlight to the previous. In the example, this would be either `[5,8,12]` or `[5,3,4]`.

### Example cases

````
positions
intervals
output

5,8,12
2,10,4
38

10
20
11

10
6
20

2,8
8,6
40

2,8
7,6
16

1,2,3,4,5,6
6,5,4,3,2,1
16
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## International "Hello, World!" (WIP) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

(Please note the special scoring for this challenge)

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/75323) code-golf question has over 900 answers and all of them print "Hello, world!" in English! If we can use hundreds of different programming languages to print that message, why can't we use hundreds of different natural languages to express that message?

## Task & scoring

Your task is to beat the answers of the [Hello, world!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/75323) challenge ("HW" challenge from now on) in different natural languages, as determined by the length ratio of the English string "Hello, world!" and the string in the natural language you pick. For example, I could pick Portuguese, hence I will have to print "Olá, mundo!" which has a length ratio of 11/13.

- if your natural language has capitalization, you must respect the original capitalization.
- if your natural language has punctuation, you must respect the original punctuation.

Then you pick the programming language you are going to write your code in. For example, I could pick Python. And you write your program. My program could be `print("Olá, mundo!")`, with a standard code-golf score of 20.

You then look for the best submission in the [HW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/75323) challenge with the same programming language you chose, let's say it has score S. (We probably need a leaderboard for challenge [HW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/75323) to make this step easier.) My score would then be (20/S)/(11/13).

Does this make any sense? Any preliminary feedback?

Comment: It's hard to define whether the grammar of the output is correct in the chosen language, especially for those who don't know the language.

Comment: @user92069 why do I need to define if the grammar is correct? "Hello, world!" doesn't look grammatically very correct either.

Answer (score 0):

## Extract an integer from another

This is a somewhat interesting problem I ran into while nanboxing: given two integers, compute their bitwise-AND and concatenate the resulting "substrings" into a new integer.

More precisely: you are provided two integers as input — an input integer and a bitmask. As output, you should produce the bitwise-AND of the two such that, given a mask with \$n\$ set bits, the corresponding bits from the input are grouped together in the first \$n\$ bits of the resulting integer.

The following pseudocode is one way to implement the function:

```lua
-- x and mask are lists of booleans
function (x, mask)
  local result=list();
  for i=1, min(x.length, mask.length) do
    if mask[i] then
      result.append(x[i]);
    end
  end
  return result;
end
```

### Example inputs and outputs

```
// In binary:
// f(x, mask) == result
f(1011, 1111) == 1011 // Select entire number
f(1010, 1010) == 11   // Select bits 1 and 3, and concatenate them
f(11001100, 01100110) == 1010 // Concatenate substrings [1:2] and [5:6]
f(11111111, 10101010) == 1111 // Concatenate bits at odd indices.

// 16-bit variants in hexadecimal:
f(BEEF, 1111) == 9
f(DEAD, 8888) == F 
f(1337, FF00) == 13
f(CODE, 7777) == 82E

// Two 64-bit variants (in hex):
f(400921FB54442D18, CODE601F15DABE57) == 111DE42C8
f(FFFE0000004010CC, 8003000000000000) == 6
```

### Specific rules

- Standard loopholes, default IO, etc. apply where not overridden.
- Input and output values must fulfill \$x \in \{b_{set}, b_{unset}\}^{n}\$ for some \$b_{set} \neq b_{unset}, n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 16}\$ of your choice. In other words:

  - You must support integers of at least 16 bits in your representation, but you may otherwise arbitrarily constrain their size - i.e. to 32-bit integers. You may also accept integers of any length through lists, arrays, strings, etc.
  - The "set" and "unset" values do not need to be of the same type or length, but they must be constant and distinct.
  - Most "linear" representations for integers are valid: integers, vectors, arrays, strings, etc.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Have fun!

Comment: Is this the PEXT BMI2 instruction? (also, possible duplicate: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37167)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate After reading the referenced challenge I think this is indeed a duplicate of that. The required algorithms are identical and other requirements seem to not affect this too much.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I've given it a read, and it definitely is the same challenge, bar minor cosmetic differences. Of course, the search did not find it when I tried searching for it...

Answer (score 0):

Write an ASPIF (clasp's ASP input format) program to find a maximum cap set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_set) for 4 dimensions.

Share the code you used to generate the ASPIF rather than ASPIF itself. This may be an ASP program.

Winner is smallest word-count (according to wc) in ASPIF format. For ASP, you can get this by running something like:

```
clingo capset.asp --mode=gringo | grep -v "\(^1 0 1 [0-9]\+ 0 0$\)\|\(^4\)" | wc -w
```

(note the grep is for excluding unary rules and #show directives neither of which are necessary for solving. The output of this is still a valid clasp program)

I have an example for four dimensions (but I have a better one I won't share right away because I'm curious to see what other people get).

```
feature(number, (one; two; three)).
feature(shading, (solid; empty; striped)).
feature(color, (red; green; purple)).
feature(shape, (oval; diamond; squiggly)).
dimension(D) :- feature(D, _).
card(c(N,F,C,S)) :-
    feature(number,N); feature(shading,F); feature(color,C); feature(shape,S).
property(c(N,F,C,S),number,N) :- card(c(N,F,C,S)).
property(c(N,F,C,S),shading,F) :- card(c(N,F,C,S)).
property(c(N,F,C,S),color,C) :- card(c(N,F,C,S)).
property(c(N,F,C,S),shape,S) :- card(c(N,F,C,S)).

{in_capset(X) : card(X)}.
:~ in_capset(X).[-1,X]

settable(D, A, B, C) :-
    feature(D, A); feature(D, B); feature(D, C); A != B; A != C; B != C.
settable(D, A, A, A) :- feature(D, A).

:- in_capset(X); in_capset(Y); in_capset(Z);
    settable(D, A, B, C) :
        dimension(D), property(X, D, A), property(Y, D, B), property(Z, D, C);
    X < Y; Y < Z.

#show in_capset/1.
```

This grounds to an ASPIF program with 9296 "words"

Comment: 4D cap set is already known and has a pattern which was found in [a challenge of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195685/78410), so it might be too trivial. Why not ask to take n as input and solve for n dimensions (without time and memory limit)?

Comment: Also, most people here are not familiar with ASP or ASPIF. It would be helpful if you include relevant links, so we can do some research before tackling the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## [PuyoPuyo] How long is my combo?

**Context:**

PuyoPuyo is a puzzle game where you and your opponent pile up colored slimes (called *puyo*) in a vertical (13*6 cells) grid. A *puyo* is one-cell big, but they come as pairs in the screen. *Puyo* pairs fall from the top to the bottom of the grid, and you can move and rotate them the Tetris way. The list of possible *puyo* pairs is the cartesian product of {'red','blue','green','yellow'} with itself. The pair sequence for a game is randomly generated for both players at the start of a round, and will be the same for both of them.

If four *puyo* (or more) of the same color are next to each other (in line, in square, Z-, S-, T-, J- or L-shaped), they disappear, awarding you points and making all the above *puyo* to fall. If when those *puyo* fall, they make another group of four (or more) they will disappear too, awarding you with more points than the first group: it is called a **two-hit combo**.

When a combo stops, whatever its length (1-hit or more), you will send damage to your opponent. The bigger the combo, the more damage is sent. Those damage are called *ojama puyo*, grey slimes that disappear only when a group disappears next to it. If your third column from the left is filled before your opponent's is, you lose. So to kill your opponent, you must manage to fill its screen before they fill yours.

**Challenge:**

With a given sequence of *puyo* pairs associated with their drop locations, output the length of the combo that has been made by this player. Shortest code in any language wins.

**Input:**

List of puyo pairs and their drop locations:

- 'r1b1r1r2y2r3...'
- '001000013102...'
- [('red','1','blue','1'),('red','1','red','2'),('yellow','2','red','3'),...]
- any sensible way you want, provided you detail how it works

Details:

- This list will never contain any "column number" outside of [1;6] (or [0;5], if 0-indexed) nor a *puyo* of a color outside of {'red','blue','green','yellow'} (or any set used for your interpretation).
- This list will always contain at most one combo sequence.
- This list will never contain unusable data, like two colors in a row, or two column indices in a row.
- If both *puyo* of a pair are dropped on the same column, the first one to come is on the top of the pair (in the example #1, red is dropped on the top of the blue on the column 1).
- *Puyo* will never remain floating in the grid, but will fall to the lowest available cell of the column they are in, even if the paired *puyo* has stopped in its column (tl;dr *puyo* pairs split).

**Output:**

A single integer indicating the length of the combo.

**Test cases:**

*Test case #1*

```
Input
y1r1

Output
0
```

*Test case #2*

```
Input
r1r2g3r3g3g2g1r2

Output
2
```

*Test case #3*

```
Input
y1r1r2r3g2g3r2g3y2y3g3g3y1y1

Output
3
```

*Test case #4*

```
Input
b1b1r2b2g3g3r2r3y4y5b6b6b5y5g4b5y4g3b6b6

Output
1
```

*Test case #5*

```
Input
y1b2b3b3b5b5y6b6b4b4

Output
1
```

*Test case #6*

```
Input
y1r1r2r3g2g3r2g3y2y3g3g3y1y1

Output
3
```

*[Test case #7 (click me!)](https://puyonexus.com/chainsim/chain/xccVX)*

```
Input
b1b2g3r4g5y6y1y2b3g4r5g6y1b2g3r4g5y6r1r2g3r4r5y6r1b2b3y4r5y6b1y2y3r4r5g6r1b2r3y4g5g6y1g2r3b4b5b6b1g2g3r4r5g6b1b2r3y4b5r6g1y2b2y3y4g4g5g6g5g6

Output
17
```

*[Test case #8 (click me!)](https://puyonexus.com/chainsim/chain/WN5SF)*

```
Input
r1r2r5r6g1r2r5g6g1y2y5g6g1y2y5g6y1g2g5y6y1b2b5y6r1b2b5r6b1r2r5b6b1y2y5b6b1y2y5b6y1r2r5y6y1r2r5y6r3r4

Output
4
```

*[Standard Loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).*

*NB: for purists, I know that the 13th row is supposed to be invisible and that* puyo *that are in that column are not considered 'linked' to nearby* puyo, *but I figured this challenge was hard enough as-is.*

**@Sandbox please comment! I'd love to hear your thoughts about such a challenge.** I will finish setting it up soon, adding some extra resources about the game (like [this one](https://puyonexus.com/chainsim/)). Questions:

- Should I reverse the "top / bottom" *puyo* of a pair rule? The way it is now, it forces to parse input as pairs. If it is reversed, golfers can take puyo one by one and sort it all by columns, making the challenge easier.
- What tags should it enter with? [code-colf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-colf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)
- I will make other test cases soon enough, but should I include a [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) as a file (via pastebin)?

Comment: "The combo"? Will there be only one combo?

Comment: Does the two puyo(s) in a pairstick to each other like in tetris?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @user202729, I'll be editing the challenge soon. This challenge will let you assume there will only be one combo. And puyo pairs are broken upon drop if need be, so that every single puyo cannot be floating in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

## Mega Man

My first polyglot challenge, enjoy!

### Validness of a program

In this challenge, a "program" doesn't take an input. This challenge doesn't care of any output, though.

An invalid program, either:

- Doesn't compile, or
- Compiles, but the program doesn't halt when executed.

A program is valid otherwise.

### The 6 Robot Masters

A **robot master** is a valid program. Their language can be chosen freely, not necessarily all same or all distinct.

There are 6 Robot Masters in total, namely **Cut Man**, **Elec Man**, **Ice Man**, **Fire Man**, **Bomb Man**, and **Guts Man**.

(Yeah, I wanted to include **Time Man** and **Oil Man** as well, but that would make this challenge too hard.)

### Weapons

The robot masters have their distictive weapons. (This doesn't mean the robot masters' source code acts as their weapon, though.) A **weapon** is an operation on a string.

- Cut Man's weapon, **Rolling Cutter**, leaves the target source's first half characters only, rounded down. Example: `Hello, world!` → `Hello,`
- Elec Man's weapon, **Thunder Beam**, eliminates all whitespaces. Example: `Hello, world!` → `Hello,world!`
- Ice Man's weapon, **Ice Slasher**, turns all uppercase ASCII letters small. Example: `Hello, world!` → `hello, world!`
- Fire Man's weapon, **Fire Storm**, turns all lowercase ASCII letters capital. Example: `Hello, world!` → `HELLO, WORLD!`
- Bomb Man's weapon, **Hyper Bomb**, eliminates the target source's first word. The behavior on the surrounding whitespaces is implementation-defined. Example: `Hello, world!` → `world!`
- Guts Man's weapon, **Super Arm**, doubles all characters. Example: `Hello, world!` → `HHeelllloo,,  wwoorrlldd!!`

### Objective

When a weapon is applied to a robot master's source code, if and only if it hits their **weakness**, the resulting code must be a valid program in the robot master's language.

- Rolling Cutter is the weakness of Elec Man.
- Thunder Beam is the weakness of Ice Man.
- Ice Slasher is the weakness of Fire Man.
- Fire Storm is the weakness of Bomb Man.
- Hyper Bomb is the weakness of Guts Man.
- Super Arm is the weakness of Cut Man.

Every other combination is not a weakness and must result in an invalid program. This includes a weapon applied to its owner.

## Scoring

This is a code golf. The score is the sum of the byte counts of all 6 source codes. The answer with the least score wins.

Comment: I find the organisation of the text quite confusing. If I've understood correctly (and I had to read it several times), the challenge boils down to this: write 6 programs, each of which is only valid when one of the weapons is applied to it. Is that right? Since the programs aren't required to implement the weapons, I don't really understand why each robot master is associated with a program. Lastly, do you mean 'execute' rather than 'compile'?

Comment: @Dingus Well, it was pretty hard to make a reference to the game. I've clarified the 'compile' and 'execute'. The challenge boils down to, Write 6 programs, each of which is valid and also valid when a weapon is applied, but is invalid when any other weapon is applied.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes more sense - I wasn't [aware of the game](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9334/92901) (living under a rock, maybe). Perhaps you should include some more context about it. It seems a bit strange that hitting a weakness results in a valid program (would have expected the opposite), but the description is clear enough. I would suggest a small tweak to 'if and only if it hits their weakness, the resulting code must *still* be a valid program'.

Comment: About 'compile', I meant in the bullet points where you define what an invalid program is. Many languages are not compiled languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Sort until overflow - [POSTED HERE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/209840/sort-until-overflow)

Comment: Now that this has been posted to main, could you delete this proposal to create more space for new answers?

Answer (score 0):

## Quineoid Triple Uniqueness Optimization

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

---

This is a variant of [Quineoid Triple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209666/45613) with the same requirements but different scoring.

Write three different programs such that when any one program is provided as input to one of the other two, you get the source of the remaining program as output. More explicitly, given programs \$A\$, \$B\$, and \$C\$, where \$f(g)\$ denotes the output obtained from inputting the text of program \$g\$ into program \$f\$, ***all*** of the following must hold:

- \$ A(B) = C \$
- \$ A(C) = B \$
- \$ B(A) = C \$
- \$ B(C) = A \$
- \$ C(A) = B \$
- \$ C(B) = A \$

## Scoring

The goal is to have the three programs be as different as possible.

Your score is the sum of:

- Number of unique bytes found in program \$A\$, but not \$B\$ or \$C\$
- Number of unique bytes found in program \$B\$, but not \$A\$ or \$C\$
- Number of unique bytes found in program \$C\$, but not \$A\$ or \$B\$

The theoretical maximum score is 256.

## Additional Rules

- Standard quine rules apply.
- Each program can be in any language. Any number of them may share languages or each may use a different language.
- Use any convenient IO format as long as each program uses a consistent convention.

  - Functions are allowed, as this counts as "any convenient IO".
- The result of feeding a program its own source code is undefined
- The result of feeding anything other than program text of either of the other two programs is undefined.
- Byte encoding should be taken into account for languages with dedicated codepages.

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

SANDBOX: this is kind of [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)-ish. Should I call it a bowling challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## Modular Chain Compression

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)

A common trope in some kolmogorov-complexity challenges is to use repeated application of the modulo operator in order to compress large integers or string hashes into some range. For example, we can squash the numbers \$13,4,16\$ into \$0,1,2\$ by taking each number mod \$7\$ and then mod \$3\$. We call this sequence the *modular chain* \$7,3\$. In general, reducing a number \$k\$ by the modular chain \$n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_i\$ is equivalent to evaluating

$$(((k\ \text{mod}\ n_1)\ \text{mod}\ n_2)\ \ldots\ )\ \text{mod}\ n_i$$

In this challenge, you will be challenged to compress an arbitrary set of integers in this way. We say the *length of the modular chain* is the number of elements in the chain (not the number of bytes).

### Input

You are given a fixed set of \$100\$ random 32-bit integers. Here they are:

```
2997344323
2062352342
1953414591
... (more on the actual post) ...
```

### Output

Via whatever means necessary (brute-force, mathematics, etc) design a modular chain to compact these numbers into a small a range as possible. The modular chain **must** have a distinct output for each input number.

### Scoring

In code-golf challenges, a modular chain is usually desirable if it achieves two things:

- It compacts the input numbers or hashes into a small range.
- It is short.

In this spirit, your score is the sum of **the maximum output number of your modular chain** and the **length of your modular chain** for the given input numbers.

Note an optimal modular chain could compress the input numbers into the range \$0 \ldots 99\$ with a single modulo operation, making the theoretical minimum score \$99 + 1 = 100\$.

The lowest scoring answer wins. You are encouraged (but not required) to post any code, mathematical background etc. that helped you design your modular chain.

Comment: Length in modulo operations or bytes?

Comment: @user253751 The number of operations. Clarified.

Answer (score 0):

## The fastest code to find a subset-sum

Given `k` sorted integers from low to high, output `n` permutations of those integers with sum as close as possible to `m` but not exceeding `m`. The output needs to be sorted from highest to lowest sum.

#### Input

`k` integers, `n`, `m` - as described above. All the `k` integers and `m` are positive 31-bit integers. Now since this is NP-complete problem, both `k` and `n` are small integers, 20 at most.

#### Output

One row for each premutation, with integers sorted from high to low. Also, the rows need to be sorted from highest to lowest sum

## The fastest code wins

For the performance test, we will use the below input:

- `k = [67, 613, 2111, 2179, 2203, 2269, 3433, 3583, 4219, 5011]`
- `m = 14,213`
- `n = 10`

Comment: 1) You might want to provide multiple test cases, so that the submissions don't use an algorithm that is fast only in some of them and very slow in the others. 2) For fair evaluation of speed, you need to run all submissions on *your* machine, so you need to provide some information about your machine's OS, RAM, CPU (also GPU if you want to allow using it). 3) Is the sum of all `k` integers guaranteed to be positive 31-bit integers? Otherwise we might face overflows during calculation. 4) I think you mean *subsets* instead of *permutations*.

Answer (score 0):

## [Double Prime Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210733/66833)

Comment: tags would be `decision-problem`, `code-golf`, `primes`, I think?

Comment: I think `if and only if x is prime` should be `if and only if n is prime`?

Comment: Additional exampleː Is this word a double primeː
`Hello Worlds`
`aardvark`
`aalii`
`Aani`

Comment: @Xwtek Is that 4 separate examples, or 1 long example?

Comment: Now that this has been posted, I've edited the post down to save space and I'd recommend you delete this proposal

Answer (score 0):

### [Unnamed]

[code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)

This challenge is based on a somewhat unusual premise; the goal is to create a rectangular program (box) which is as large as possible, where each row and column will be a solution to a different challenge on this site.

For example, a 3×4 box might look like this:

```
abcd
 :-]
1234
```

As all solutions will be read from left to right or top to bottom, this would expand into seven programs:

```
abcd
 :-]
1234
a 1
b:2
c-3
d]4
```

For an answer to be valid, each one of these must be a valid solution to a different challenge on this site, in the same language. The box may be padded by whitespace, but **must** be rectangular (`x` groups of `y` bytes, separated by newlines). This is code bowling, so the longest answer in bytes wins.

Additional rules/clarifications:

- Solutions cannot contain newlines (because otherwise they would be two separate rows/columns)
- Yes, it will be possible to trivially get very high scores with some languages (like unary), but as with most challenges it's a competition within each language
- Solutions do not have to be original, but ones copied from other answers should link to them

Comment: Unary won't be able to compete because the number of challenges on our site is lower than most Unary programs. It will be very hard to compete even in golfing languages, as the answerer will need to manually find the appropriate challenge to use. I don't really think a challenge that makes use of "all challenges on our site" is fun.

Comment: @Bubbler Yeah, now that I think about it I agree. I still like the concept, maybe there's something similar that might actually be fun.

Comment: Maybe you could select a subset of challenges - something like what was done for [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/206595/92901)?

Comment: @Dingus Good idea! I'll see if I can fix a few other things, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Targeted sum and difference of a sequence**

You are given two things: a target integer(not necessarily positive) **n**, and a sorted list/array/etc. of non-negative integers **a**. (The list will have at least two elements). Your goal is to choose one element of **a** as your total, and then one by one, take elements of **a**, and either add or subtract them from your total. Print out all possible combinations(duplicates can be removed, but it is optional) of `[a_1]±[a_2]±[a_3]` or return them as a list/array/etc. .

In other words, find all solutions to `n=[a_1]±[a_2]±[a_3]`. The first element of **a** is not guaranteed to be `a_1`, nor is the second element guaranteed to be `n_2`.

Test cases:

```
n = 10, a = [1,2,3,4] :  10 = 1+2+3+4 and 2+1+3+4 ...
# The output should be 1+2+3+4(and 4+2+3+1, and every combination like that)
n = 1, a = [2,3]: 1 = 3-2, so 3-2. 
# (-2+3 wouldn't work, since it is strictly addition or subtraction of positive integers).
# -2 isn't a part of [2,3]. You should think of the steps as [a_1]±[a_2]±[a_3].
# n = -5, a = [0,5,1]. -5 = 0-5, and nothing else.
n=95, a = [50,50,5]. 95 = 50+50-5, 50-5+50. (A second 50+50-5 is optional)
```

Criteria: Shortest code wins

**Meta**:

Is this clear enough(and what should I do to make this more clear)? Also, has this been done before? Finally, should I remove the restriction on the first number being positive?

Thank You!

Comment: What do you mean by "The first element of a is not guaranteed to be `a_1`"?

Answer (score 0):

## [Word Length-Sum Multiples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211411/66833)

Comment: Now that this has been posted, I've edited it down to save space and I'd recommend you delete the proposal

Answer (score 0):

A centered hexagonal number is a centered figurate number that represents a hexagon with a dot in the center and all other dots surrounding the center dot in a hexagonal lattice.

**Illustration of initial terms:**

```
                                 o o o o
                   o o o        o o o o o
         o o      o o o o      o o o o o o
   o    o o o    o o o o o    o o o o o o o
         o o      o o o o      o o o o o o
                   o o o        o o o o o
                                 o o o o

   1      7          19             37
```

Write a function that takes an integer \$n\$ and returns `"Invalid"` if \$n\$ is not a centered hexagonal number or its illustration as a multiline rectangular string otherwise.

**Sample Output :-**

```js
hexLattice(1) ➞ " o "
// o

hexLattice(7) ➞ "  o o  \n o o o \n  o o  "
//  o o
// o o o
//  o o

hexLattice(19) ➞ "   o o o   \n  o o o o  \n o o o o o \n  o o o o  \n   o o o   "
//   o o o
//  o o o o
// o o o o o
//  o o o o
//   o o o

hexLattice(21) ➞ "Invalid"
```

**Rules**

Shortest Code Wins!

Comment: I like the challenge concept! Usually, we advise against input validation; that is, rather than outputting "Invalid", solutions should assume the input is valid, though if you do that this challenge is almost a duplicate and so I think in this case it could make for an interesting challenge to leave it in.

Comment: Another thing is usually we encourage flexible input/output formatting; in this case, in addition to a multiline string, I would also allow a list of strings or a matrix of characters as output, and rather than strictly outputting "Invalid", I would suggest allowing solutions to state any reasonable parameters for how they'll indicate invalid input.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66708/31625)-ish. There are several other hexagon related challenges but this was the only one I could find that required computing the centred hexagonal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Socially distanced seating

Lord Lloyd Warbler wants to minimise the harm to his theatre's seating capacity for his hit show, Birds, of maintaining social distancing.

The social distancing rules in Westendland are:

- Groups may sit together without distancing
- Between groups there must be at least 2 empty seats along the row, and 1 empty row in front and behind.
- The closest diagonal permitted is a knight's move - only 1 horizontal space empty.

Diagrams:

```
 A _ _ B

 A
 _
 B

 A _ _
 _ _ B
```

Given a list of group sizes and the theatre size (rows and columns), can you pack them all into the theatre? Groups can sit in any contiguous (connected) arrangement of seats.

### Sample tests

```
(Rows, cols), [groups] -> canFitBool
(1,1), [1] -> true
(2,2), [1,1] -> false
(2,3), [1,1] -> true   // knight's move
(5,2), [4,4] -> true   // 2x2 in rows a,b, gap in c, 2x2 in d,e
```

### questionmarks

- Should I just provide a list of cases of varying difficulty? Like, some of these could be pretty difficult.
- Is the knight's move rule too complicated?
- Is the contiguous rule too permissive, and therefore complicated? It could mean some edge cases are possible if you have a weird shaped group. Could make it rectangular blocks only?

Comment: _Groups can sit in any contiguous (connected) arrangement of seats_ You need to decide, and specify in the text, if _contiguous_ means 4-connectivity (up, down, left, right) or 8-connectivity (diagonals count as connected too)

Answer (score 0):

## Terminal Punch Card

*moved because apparently it's not clear enough.*

So back in the day, computers didn't have fancy keyboard and mouse inputs, and didn't have your fancy screens. Instead they had punch cards.

[image: Punch card]

Punch cards punchers punched (try saying that 10 times fast) a hole out of a card to represent a 1-bit, and left it filled to represent a 0-bit. The cards were some number of holes wide, with each hole representing a bit in a byte.

Recently, you discovered an old mainframe at your local university that accepted punch cards that were 8 holes wide. For this challenge, you will be given data as an input, and your job is to punch a punch card to the terminal output, like this:

```
Hello, World!

: *  *   :
: **  * *:
: ** **  :
: ** **  :
: ** ****:
:  * **  :
:  *     :
: * * ***:
: ** ****:
: ***  * :
: ** **  :
: **  *  :
:  *    *:
```

The input will be a string or bytes representing the punched data payload. The output data must include rows, which start and end with a `:`, and have 8 bits between them, represented as a   for 0, or a `*` for 1. There must be one row for each byte of data.

Here's the catch: The punch card puncher only punched one hole at a time, so in your program, must print (or add to the output string) only one character at a time.

Example of unacceptable method call:

```python
# `binary` is some string with the binary bits.
print(":" + binary.replace("0", " ").replace("1", "*") + ":")
```

Acceptable method call:

```python
for bit in binary:
   print(bit == "1" ? "*" : " ", "")
```

Also acceptable method call:

```python
output = ""
for bit in binary:
   output += bit == "1" ? "*" : " "
```

The challenge is code golf, so least number of bytes wins. Standard rules/loopholes are in effect.

Comment: A word about catches before we even discuss observability and clarity issues:  Catches are rarely a good idea for two reasons.  The first is that challenge writers frequently add catches because they somehow feel their challenge is deficient or too easy and want to salvage it somehow.  This coping mechanism usually fails, they are better off writing a new challenge.

Comment: Note also there are already comments [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212010/terminal-punch-card-moved-to-sandbox) regarding observability, assuming language features, and assuming implementation details

Comment: The second, which I think is more relevant to you, is that structuring your challenge with a catch is often confusing.  You have already written what is a complete challenge, but then in the last 10% or so the whole task changes.  Some people don't read the whole challenge once they think they have it, miss the last bit or become frustrated when things are pulled out from under them.  Regardless of how you feel about these people, It is really just better to phrase your challenge in a straight forward and upfront way.  Nothing should seem tacked on if you can avoid it.

Comment: One way you could easily make your catch observable is to take a string and an index and output the character at that index.  Of course answerers can just produce the entire string and index it, but they could already do that with your existing version (probably, it's a little unclear).

Answer (score 0):

## Count the strokes of an ASCII character

### Objective

Given a printable ASCII character (0x21 – 0x7E), count its strokes (as handwritten), then output it.

**Note:** The strokes are based on how **I** write the characters. Those with potential controversy are marked `*` below.

### Mapping

```
       ! → 2  " → 2  # → 4  $ → 2* % → 3* & → 1* ' → 1
( → 1  ) → 1  * → 3* + → 2  , → 1  - → 1  . → 1  / → 1
0 → 1* 1 → 1* 2 → 1  3 → 1  4 → 2  5 → 2  6 → 1  7 → 2*
8 → 1* 9 → 1  : → 2  ; → 2  < → 1  = → 2  > → 1  ? → 2
@ → 1  A → 3* B → 2  C → 1  D → 2  E → 3* F → 3  G → 2
H → 3  I → 3* J → 1* K → 2* L → 1  M → 4* N → 3* O → 1
P → 2  Q → 1* R → 2  S → 1  T → 2  U → 1  V → 1  W → 1
X → 2  Y → 2  Z → 2* [ → 1  \ → 1  ] → 1  ^ → 1  _ → 1
` → 1  a → 1  b → 1  c → 1  d → 1* e → 1  f → 2  g → 2*
h → 1  i → 2  j → 2  k → 2  l → 1  m → 1  n → 1  o → 1
p → 1  q → 1  r → 1  s → 1  t → 2  u → 1  v → 1  w → 1
x → 2  y → 2  z → 2* { → 1  | → 1  } → 1  ~ → 1
```

### Rule

- Every character outside of U+0021 – U+007E falls in *don't care* situation.

Comment: There's no requirement for the `*`s, because people have to follow your specification anyway. If there's a way to solve this beyond simple compression, then this challenge will be good.

Comment: Can we take input as an ASCII codepoint?

Comment: Also can I just say how the hell do you write `Q` with only one stroke?

Comment: Does "don't care" mean "assume we won't be given this" or "it doesn't matter what you output"?

Comment: @pxeger ASCII codepoint is acceptable. "Don't care" means both. For the Q, the tail bisects the bowl, so it can be written in one stroke.

Answer (score 0):

## Position my geohashes

### The Challenge

This is the reverse challenge of [Geohash my positions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212301/geohash-my-positions/). Given a Geohash string of length 8, convert it to a latitude and a longitude. The conversion is done by the following algorithm, using `u09tunqu` as an example input.

- For each character of the Geohash string, find its 0-indexed position in the map `0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz`.

  - `u09tunqu` becomes `26 0 9 25 26 20 22 26`
- Convert each integer into a binary string of length 5.

  - `26 0 9 25 26 20 22 26` becomes `11010 00000 01001 11001 11010 10100 10110 11010`
- Join the binary strings together.

  - `11010 00000 01001 11001 11010 10100 10110 11010` becomes `1101000000010011100111010101001011011010`
- Separate the odd positions in the joined binary string from the even positions. These represent the longitude and latitude, respectively.

  - `1101000000010011100111010101001011011010` becomes `10000001101000011011` (odd positions: longitude) and `11000101011111001100` (even positions: latitude).
- The latitude should be somewhere in the range (-90, 90). Narrow down the range, based on the first character in the latitude binary string. If the first character is `0`, the latitude should converge to the lower half of this range, i.e. (-90, 0). If the first character is `1`, the latitude should converge to the upper half of this range, i.e. (0, 90).

  - The 1st character in `11000101011111001100` is `1`, so the new range becomes (0, 90).
- The remaining characters in the binary string are to be processed in the same way, where `0` represents the lower half of the new range and `1` represents the upper half of the new range.

  - The 2nd character in `11000101011111001100` is `1`, so the new range becomes (45, 90).
  - The 3rd character in `11000101011111001100` is `0`, so the new range becomes (45.0, 67.5).
  - The 4th character in `11000101011111001100` is `0`, so the new range becomes (45.0, 56.25).
  - The 5th character in `11000101011111001100` is `0`, so the new range becomes (45.0, 50.625).
  - The 6th character in `11000101011111001100` is `1`, so the new range becomes (47.8125, 50.625).
  - ...
  - The 20th character in `11000101011111001100` is `0`, so the final range becomes (48.85826, 48.85843).
- The final latitude is the midpoint of the final range.

  - (48.85826, 48.85843) becomes 48.85835
- Repeat the same process for the longitude, starting from the range (-180, 180)

  - `10000001101000011011` becomes 2.29460
- Output the final latitude and longitude.

  - `u09tunqu` becomes `48.85835, 2.29460`

#### Input

A string of length 8, consisting only of the characters `0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz`.

#### Output

Two signed floats in the ranges (-90.0, 90.0) and (-180.0, 180.0) representing the corresponding latitude and longitude.

### Test cases

```
u09tunqu → (48.85835, 2.2946)
dr5r7p62 → (40.68933, -74.04459)
stq4s8cf → (29.97525, 31.13783)
75cm2txp → (-22.9519, -43.21043)
usdkfsq8 → (71.17089, 25.78302)
zzzzzzzz → (89.99991, 179.99983)
00000000 → (-89.99991, -179.99983)
ezs42s00 → (42.60507, -5.60286)
7zzzzzzz → (-0.00009, -0.00017)
```

### General remarks

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer using the fewest bytes in each language wins.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/), [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Please include a [Try it Online](https://tio.run/#)-link or equivalent to demonstrate your code working.
- Please motivate your answer with an explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

## AOG Day 6: Filtering the Playlist

*I promise the next one will be better*

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

You've sent the invitations for the party (and made the postperson do a whole lot more work than they should have, smh), made the decorations as interesting as possible (who doesn't love a painstakingly written quine) and made sure that the event won't kill anyone (at least, not due to COVID). The next thing that needs to be planned is the music.

Now, of course, you could go ahead and create a YouTube playlist by hand, but that's way too tedious and, well, predictable. Instead, you've decided to write a program that randomly chooses songs from the music genre (I know...very efficient isn't it).

But of course, there's just one problem with that plan: there's a very small chance that a song selected at random might just [ruin the party vibes for everyone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) (even though people such as myself would consider it a Christmas miracle, others would probably see it as a lame stunt and potentially leave the party).

Thankfully, the magic of code allows us to check the html of the YouTube video before hand to tell if it is indeed a rickroll.

### The Challenge

Given a YouTube link as input (not shortened, but a full standard link), retrieve the title and description of the video and output whether or not it is a rickroll. In order for a video to be considered a rickroll, it must have either the unbroken phrase `Never Gonna Give You Up` or `Rickroll` in the title or description.

### Test Cases

*Under construction*

Comment: How about checking the top 5 comments for the unbroken phrase Never Gonna Give You Up or Rickroll as well? Would that make it inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

## English Stroke Count Alphabet

In a Chinese glossary/index for any given book, to find terms that are contained within the book and because Chinese doesn't have an alphabet like in English, they are sorted by stroke count instead. `(一畫 = 1 stroke，二畫 = 2 strokes，三畫 = 3 strokes，四畫 = 4 strokes，and so on)`

An English glossary, having an alphabet, is naturally sorted alphabetically. For this challenge, we flip that idea to the Chinese manner. And we'll follow some Chinese writing rules to help determine stroke order for the alphabet below.

Take 口 (kou) for example, a simple square. You'd think it is 4 strokes, but it is actually 3. The 1st being the left vertical line, the 2nd being the top horizontal and right vertical in one fluid stroke, and the 3rd being the lower horizontal line. This pattern, among others, holds relatively true across Chinese characters. For sake of simplicity though, and for some diversity in the English Stroke Count Alphabet, this will be the primary pattern used.

First, I need to define stroke count for each letter. For sake of simplicity, and somewhat *subjectively*, I'll use the characters as they appear below. If there are any arguments why a letter should have a different stroke count, please make your case, but in order to promote diversity in stroke counts, I made some personal judgment calls. These stroke counts could easily change with different fonts.

`A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`

`3 3 1 2 4 3 2 3 3 1 3 2 4 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 1 2 4 2 3 3`

`a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z`

`2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 4 2 2 3`

Letters with equal stroke counts should retain the original alphabetic order as before. So the English Stroke Order Alphabet is as follows. (If I made an error, please say as much, there are a lot of examples that I might have to adjust)

`C J O S U D G L P Q T V X A B F H I K N R Y Z E M W`

`c o s a b d e f g h j l n p q r t u v x y i k m z w`

**The Challenge** Given a non-empty string input containing a sentence/series of words, or a list of words, organize all words according to this new English Stroke Count alphabet. Output can be either a string, or a list of properly words is a single string of properly organized words, including duplicates should they exist.

**Note 1:** If upper and lowercase for the same letter have the same stroke count, uppercase letters take precedence.

- "Cousin" precedes "cousin"
- "father" precedes "Father" (because lowercase f is 2 strokes, while the uppercase is 3)
- "Stop" precedes "soap" (while the o would precede t in stroke count, uppercase S precedes lowercase s)
- KO precedes kO  (K precedes k)
- kO precedes ko  (O precedes o)

**Note 2:** I've intentionally avoided weird words in input. Inputs such as "WeIrD", "COVID-19". Input will never include any numbers, punctuation, or special characters.

**Input / Output**

`"It was the best of times it was the worst of tImes" / "of of best the the tImes times It it worst was was"`

`["When", "life", "gives", "you", "lemons", "make", "Lemonade"] / ["gives", "Lemonade", "lemons", "life", "you", "When", "make"]`

`[The, journey, of, a, thousand, miles, begins, with, one, step,] / [of, one, step, The, a, begins, journey, thousand, miles, with]`

`"English Stroke Count Alphabet" / "Count Stroke Alphabet English"`

`"A man a plan a canal panama" / "canal a a panama plan A man"`

`"Carry on my wayward son" / "Carry on son my wayward"`

`"Close our store and begin destroying every flower green house just lose no people quietly rather than using vexing xrays yesterday it killed my zoo wombat" / Same as input` (If you can write a better sentence than above, I'd be much appreciated.)

`["May", "the", "Force", "be", "with", "you"] / ["be", "the", "you", "Force", "May", "with"]`

`[Im, going, to, make, him, an, offer, he, cant, refuse] / [cant, offer, an, going, he, him, refuse, to, Im, make]`

`"jello Jello JellO JEllo JELlo JELlO JELLO" / "JellO Jello JELLO JELlO JELlo JEllo jello"`

`"We suffer more often In imagination than IN reality" / "often suffer reality than In IN imagination more We"`

`"Code Golf and Coding Challenges" / "Code Coding Challenges Golf and"`

`["Do", "or", "DO", "not", "there", "is", "no", "try"] / ["or", "DO", "Do", "no", "not", "there", "try", "is"]`

`"Failure the best teacher is" / "best teacher the Failure is"`

`"Can you tell that I am a Star Wars fan" / "Can Star a am fan tell that you I Wars"`

`[enough examples no more words] / [enough examples no more words]`

Comment: If `I` is 3, then surely `i` is 4, no? Similarly for `J` vs `j`.

Comment: You should be more lenient about input. E.g. allow a list of words.

Comment: "Uppercase letters take precedence when determining stroke counts, should they be equal." means there's just a single case-sensitive alphabet. It'd be more interesting if uppercase matching lowercase on stroke counts would only be used as a tie breaker.

Comment: @Adám As per point 1, I can see the argument. I can make that change, but it'll likely take a second to get all of the examples in line. Point 2, that input format seems adequate. Point 3, I think I know what you mean. And I'm pretty certain that that's what I was intending, but I had poor wording.

Comment: No rush. I recommend sandboxing for at least one week.

Comment: You should add `KD` vs `kO` and `kO` vs `ko` to the examples for Note 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "that input format seems adequate", but please familiarise yourself with [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/43319).

Comment: @Adám I'd like to add one thing about how stroke count works in Mandarin. 口 (kou) in Mandarin appears to be a square, and you'd think it has 4 strokes, but it actually has 3. The 1st stroke is the left vertical line, the 2nd stroke is the top horizontal and right vertical line, and the 3rd and final stroke is the bottom horizontal line. These patterns hold fairly true across Chinese characters. In the case of the letter `i`, I actually see 3 strokes instead of your suggested 4. The 1st being the slight horizontal tick and vertical line, the 2nd being the bottom line, and the 3rd for the dot.

Comment: I see, but then `J` should be 1, no? 一丿

Comment: @Adám Correct, I wasn't necessarily thinking of that when I made the challenge, but I'll add the explanation and make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a die of given number of faces

### Objective

Given an integer \$n\$ greater than 3, identify an \$n\$-sided die with the "greatest" symmetry, then decompose \$n\$ to numbers of faces grouped up to the symmetry, and then output the decomposition.

### Symmetry

A die can have one of the following symmetries, from the greatest and with descending order:

- \$I_h\$, **icosahedral** symmetry
- \$O_h\$, **octahedral** symmetry
- \$T_d\$, **tetrahedral** symmetry
- \$D_{ph}\$, \$p\$-fold **prismatic** symmetry, in ascending order on \$p\$, where \$p\$ is an odd prime number

Note that every other symmetry is redundant.

### Faces

A die of each symmetry can have the following faces:

- For a die of symmetry \$I_h\$:

  - Optionally \$12\$ faces, those from a [dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)
  - Optionally \$20\$ faces, those from an [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron)
  - Optionally \$30\$ faces, those from a [rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron)
  - Optionally \$60\$ faces, those from a [deltoidal hexecontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoidal_hexecontahedron)
  - Zero or more sets of \$120\$ faces, those from a [disdyakis triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_triacontahedron)
- For a die of symmetry \$O_h\$:

  - Optionally \$6\$ faces, those from a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube)
  - Optionally \$8\$ faces, those from an [octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron)
  - Optionally \$12\$ faces, those from a [rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron)
  - Optionally \$24\$ faces, those from a [deltoidal icositetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoidal_icositetrahedron)
  - Zero or more sets of \$48\$ faces, those from a [disdyakis dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_dodecahedron)
- For a die of symmetry \$T_d\$:

  - Optionally \$4\$ faces, those from a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)
  - Optionally \$6\$ faces, those from a cube
  - Optionally \$12\$ faces, those from a [triakis tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triakis_tetrahedron)
  - Zero or more sets of \$24\$ faces, those from a [tetrakis hexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrakis_hexahedron)
- For a die of symmetry \$D_{ph}\$:

  - Optionally \$2\$ faces, those from base faces of a \$p\$-gonal prism
  - Optionally \$p\$ faces, those from side faces of a \$p\$-gonal prism
  - Optionally \$2p\$ faces, those from a \$p\$-gonal [bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid)
  - Zero of more sets \$4p\$ faces, those from a \$2p\$-gonal bipyramid

Note that faces from the [Catalan solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_solid) that are not mentioned here are redundant.

### Rules

- The input and output format doesn't matter. Possible choices of output format include:

  - A list, sorted or unsorted
  - A multiset
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation. Especially, integers that are 3 or less.

### Examples

- For \$n=4\$, the die has \$T_d\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(4)\$, with the die being a tetrahedron.
- For \$n=5\$, the die has \$D_{3h}\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(2,3)\$, with the die being a triangular prism.
- For \$n=6\$, the die has \$O_h\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(6)\$, with the die being a cube.
- For \$n=7\$, the die has \$D_{5h}\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(2,5)\$, with the die being a pentagonal prism.
- For \$n=8\$, the die has \$O_h\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(8)\$, with the die being an octahedron.
- For \$n=9\$, the die has \$D_{3h}\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(3,6)\$, with the die being a truncated triangular bipyramid. Note that the die won't have \$D_{7h}\$ symmetry because \$D_{3h}\$ is greater.
- For \$n=10\$, the die has \$T_d\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(4,6)\$, with the die being a chamfered tetrahedron. Note that this is different than the usual d10, which is a pentagonal trapezohedron.
- For \$n=11\$, the die has \$D_{3h}\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(2,3,6)\$.
- For \$n=12\$, the die has \$I_h\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(12)\$, with the die being a dodecahedron. Note that due to the greater symmetry, dodecahedron supersedes rhombic dodecahedron and triakis tetrahedron.
- For \$n=100\$, the die has \$T_d\$ symmetry, so \$n\$ decomposes to \$(4,24,24,24,24)\$. Note that this is different than usual Zocchihedron, which has prismatic symmtery.

Note that, if \$p\$ and \$p+2\$ are twin primes, \$p+2\$ will always decompose to \$(2,p)\$.

### Ungolfed solution

#### Haskell

This implementation mimics the `ReadP` parser.

```
import Control.Monad

type DResult = [([Int], Int)]
type DParser = DResult -> DResult

returnD :: Int -> DResult
returnD n = [([],n)]

pfail :: DParser
pfail _ = []

get :: Int -> DParser
get m results = do
    (ns, n) <- results
    guard (m <= n)
    return (m:ns, n - m)

many :: DParser -> DParser
many p results = let
    results2 = p results
    in case results2 of
        [] -> results
        _  -> results ++ many p results2

optional :: DParser -> DParser
optional p results = p results ++ results

run :: DParser
run = filter ((0==) . snd)

(<++) :: DParser -> DParser -> DParser
(<++) p q results = case p results of
    [] -> q results
    results2 -> results2

decomposeDph :: Int -> DParser
decomposeDph prismFold = run . optional (get 2) . optional (get prismFold) . optional (get (2*prismFold)) . many (get (4*prismFold))

decomposeTd :: DParser
decomposeTd = run . optional (get 4) . optional (get 6) . optional (get 12) . many (get 24)

decomposeOh :: DParser
decomposeOh = run . optional (get 6) . optional (get 8) . optional (get 12) . optional (get 24) . many (get 48)

decomposeIh :: DParser
decomposeIh = run . optional (get 12) . optional (get 20) . optional (get 30) . optional (get 60) . many (get 120)

decomposeDie :: Int -> [Int]
decomposeDie n = fst . head $ foldr (<++) pfail (decomposeIh : decomposeOh : decomposeTd : map decomposeDph [3,5..]) (returnD n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Catch the fruit (Abandoned) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

I feel that this is too complex to be a good code-golf question, and has too many things to specify for it to be anywhere near serviceable. Anybody willing to make this idea into a proper question can do so.

Implement a osu!catch style game.

## Introduction

osu!catch is a rhythm game where the player moves a "basket" to catch "fruits" falling from the top of the screen to the beat of a song. Think pong, but with timing.

It is **highly** recommended to [watch this video](https://youtu.be/6WKZE2HPOK8?t=43) before reading the question.

Here's a gameplay example from Bubbler: [[osu!catch] Hitsuji to Ojisan - XENO [Spec's Overdose]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLsPCHzakK8&ab_channel=WoosukKwak)

## Input

You are required to take the following inputs:

- Time: How long your program is supposed to run.
- Approach Rate: This is the speed at which the "fruits" are supposed to fall down.
- Beatmap: An array of [time, x position, value] triplets where:

  - Time: you must support time in seconds, at the very least. Higher precision is encouraged.
  - X position: Where it will fall from.
  - Value: The size of the "fruit" will decrease with it's value.

## Gameplay

### Play area

- The canvas must be in a 4:3 aspect ratio.
- The score must be displayed at the top of the screen, in the middle. You do not need to align it.
- The score starts at 0.
- Use a dark background(#222222, preferably).

### The player

- The player must be of a rectangular shape, white in color.
- Height: 1/50 of canvas height, Width: 1/6 of canvas width.
- The player must be at the bottom of the screen, movable using any two keys of your choice.
- The player must have a "dash" button. Their speed must increase 0.5x when they hold the dash button.
- When the player collects a fruit, it must disappear, and it's value must be added to the score.
- When the player misses a fruit, there should be an indicative visual cue where the fruit fell.(a small red square, preferably)
- The player must be constrained within the canvas.

### Fruits

- Fruit must be square in shape, and red in color.
- Fruits must fall from the top of the screen, outside the viewport(unless unsupported).
- Max fruit size is 0.1 × height. Size scales inversely with value.
- Fruit speed must be related to the approach rate i.e. Higher approach rate must make the fruits fall faster. You may do this however you like, but please be reasonable.
- The lower edge of the fruit must touch the bottom of the screen at it's time value.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.

---

## Meta

- Is the specification simple enough?
- I am planning on making a separate [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenge for this. Is that a better idea?
- Is the specfication clear?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: You *most likely* already have this in mind, but you can add the [tag:game] tag. Also, I think you should not leave too many stuff to the golfers, as they could do anything with the oppurtunities (e.g they could just increase the speed by 0 by pressing the dash button). What happens when the player goes outside the canvas?

Comment: @SunnnyMoon Good points. I've changed those things, and I'll proofread it again to see if there are any more mistakes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## Isomorphic Modular Arithmetic

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

For this question, we define \$U(n)\$ as the group consisting of a number below \$n\$ that is coprime to n (1 included but 0 doesn't) and multiplication as group operator.

Your task is to print every integer (so it's an infinite loop, but there should be output during looping) and group it into lines so that:

1. The line consists of a sequence of sorted number so that the \$U\$ group based on each number is isomorphic
2. The output itself has to be sorted based on the first number on each line
3. Every number have to be eventually outputted given enough time.

A pair of groups \$(X,\times_A)\$ and \$(X,\times_B)\$ is called isomorphic if there is a pair of functions \$f : X\to X\$ and \$g:X\to X\$ so that:

\$
f(g(x)) = x = g(f(x)) \text{ (i.e. they are inverses)}
\$

\$
f(x) \times_B f(y) = f(x \times_A y)
\$

\$
g(x) \times_A g(y) = g(x \times_B y)
\$

The shortest code wins.

### Example

U(2) consists of only one element 1.
U(3) and U(4) is isomorphic because both contains only 2 elements (former 1, 2 and latter 1, 3. 2 is excluded because 2 divides 4) and the table of multiplication is identical aside of replacement of 2 and 3.
Less trivially U(8) and U(12) is isomorphic, but not U(5)
the elements of U(8) is 1,3,5,7
the elements of U(12) is 1,5,7,11
the elements of U(5) is 1,2,3,4
Look at the table of multiplication:

```
    U(8)          U(12)          U(5)     
  1 3 5 1       1  5  7 11     1 2 3 4
1 1 3 5 7    1  1  5  7 11   1 1 2 3 4
3 3 1 7 5    5  5  1 11  7   2 2 4 1 3
5 5 7 1 3    7  7 11  1  5   3 3 1 4 2
7 7 5 3 1   11 11  7  5  1   4 4 3 2 1
```

By replacing 1 <-> 1, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 7, 7 <-> 11, the table of multiplication for U(8) and U(12) is identical. U(8) and U(5) is not, as n * n = 1 for any n in U(8), but 2*2 = 4 and 1*1 = 1 in U(5). If there is such a pair f : U(8) -> U(5) and g : U(5) -> U(8), then
g(2*2)=g(4) <=> g(2)*g(2)=g(4) <=> 1 = g(4) <=> g(1) * g(1) = g(4) <=> g(1*1) = g(4) <=> f(g(1*1)) = f(g(4)) <=> 1*1=4 <=> 1=4, which is a contradiction.

Even less obviously U(7) and U(9) are isomorphic, the multiplication table is:

```
   U(7)           U(9)
1 3 2 5 4 6   1 2 4 5 7 8
3 2 6 1 5 4   2 4 8 1 5 7
2 6 4 3 1 5   4 8 7 2 1 5
5 1 3 4 6 2   5 1 2 7 8 4
4 5 1 6 2 3   7 5 1 8 4 2
6 4 5 2 3 1   8 7 5 4 2 1
```

Aside of swapping the row and column (has been done) and relabeling, the multiplication table is identical, So, they are symmetric

Output for 2-15

```
2
3 4 6
5 10
7 9
8 
11
13
14
15
```

Comment: Your opening sentence doesn't quite define a group.  Do you mean a group *generated* by the coprime and multiplication?  It seems like the most logical choice.

Comment: I am starting to doubt that since the result is always isomorphic to the integers under addition, and completely ignores n.  Do you maybe mean the group generated by the coprime and multiplication *on the cyclic group of order n*?  This makes more sense, but not a whole ton of sense.  I think if you explained the output requirements more directly it would be easier.  As it stands I do not understand them at all.

Comment: @WheatWizard I mean group generated by coprime and multiplication on the cyclic group of order n

Comment: You still haven't actually changed the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

## Topologies on Rational Numbers (WIP)

### Objective

Construct a subset \$P\$ of \$\mathbb{Q}\$ such that:

- \$P\$ is neither open nor closed in \$\mathbb{Q}\$ as a subspace of \$\mathbb{R}\$, and
- \$P\$ is open but not closed in \$\mathbb{Q}\$ as a subspace of \$\mathbb{R}_l\$.

Or, in other words, construct a subset \$P\$ of \$\mathbb{Q}\$ such that:

- There exists \$p \in P\$ such that, there **doesn't** exist an open interval \$p \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}\$ such that, \$\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b) \subset P\$.
- For every \$p \in P\$, there exists a half-open interval \$p \in [a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}\$ such that, \$\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b) \subset P\$.
- There exists \$p \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus P\$ such that, there **doesn't** exist a half-open interval \$p \in [a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}\$ such that, \$\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b) \subset \mathbb{Q} \setminus P\$.

### Notes and Rules

- Note that \$P\$ is necessarily infinite, and thus cannot be represented as an associative container. One way of representing \$P\$ is to have a function \$f : \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Z}_2\$ that halts for every input, where \$\mathbb{Z}_2\$ is the set of the boolean values. Then \$p \in P\$ shall satisfy iff \$f(p)\$ is true.
- The representation of \$\mathbb{Q}\$ must be exact. Thus you cannot have floating-point values as an input. Though native rational-number arithmetic will be preferred, you may use two **arbitrary-length** integers as an input. In this case, the fraction is assumed to be irreducible and to have a positive denominator. Otherwise, the fraction falls in *don't care* situation.
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.

### Example

An example of such \$P\$ is:

$$
\mathbb{Q} \cap ((0,1) \cup [2,3))
$$

**Work in progress due to a trivial example.**

Comment: Is there a way you can frame this question without topology? At the moment I think participation would be very low due to the high background knowledge demanded.

Answer (score 0):

## Write a program that mimics the output of the command `env` (with no arguments).

The program should print (to standard output, or closest equivalent) a list of all current environment variables, with each variable on it's own line. The name and content of a variable should be separated by an equal sign.

Here's a grammar:

```
line ::= name "=" contents
output ::= (line "\n")*
```

No using the `env` command, or any 1 command that completes the challenge on its own.

shortest code wins.

Comment: Can we use built-ins the get environment variables?

Comment: @Adám If you mean "Can we use built-ins to get the environment variables", yes, I don't see a reason you couldn't, and otherwise it might be impossible to get them in some languages.

Comment: And I assume (ba|k|c|…)sh cannot participate?

Comment: @Adám If they can find a way to get a list of environment variables without using `env`, I guess they could, unless I'm missing some other command that produces the same output. There's a lot of languages that can't complete the challenge (mostly esoteric ones), but they aren't technically *banned*.

Comment: How about `set` on Windows/DOS?

Comment: @Adám I have no experience with windows, does it have similar functionality to `env`? if so then no.

Comment: It is indeed. Note: As a beginner challenge writer (you've never posted a challenge before), you should [avoid do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/43319) challenges.

Comment: @Adám isn't "don't use a builtin that does exactly what you need" a standard loophole?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @Adám Huh, I guess you're right. I just don't want to have the challenge solved before it's even posted, with the 3 character bash program `env`. Does trying to prevent 1 cheeky answer really put you in the same category as forbidding something random?

Comment: Does it really bother you that much that someone will post `env` or `set` as a solution? You're under no obligation to upvote or accept such an answer.

Comment: @Adám here's something you linked me: "A commonly used non-observable requirement is to avoid using a library function that solves the entire challenge. I believe these rules are OK. Like other non-observable requirements, one can find borderline cases of whether a built-in function solves all of the task or not, but the benefits of higher-quality answers outweigh the costs." this certainly seems to apply here.

Comment: @Adám I've never posted anything because whenever I post a question to the sandbox  all I get is reasons why my question is bad. And putting any additional rules whatsoever gets the same "no X without Y" response. Then people don't elaborate on anything.

Comment: Don't be dismayed. We've all been there. Writing challenges is notoriously hard, especially for beginners. If you look at my account, I have lots of well-received challenges, but dig in, and you'll find that many of my early ones were flawed. I highly recommend answering a lot more existing challenges, before you attempt at writing your own. And when you do, decide on a simple unique task (this is hard, as a lot of obvious tasks have already been posted), with no special rules; just vanilla code golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the longest streak of Fibonacci numbers on the Ulam spiral

### Fibonacci numbers

[Fibonacci numbers](https://oeis.org/A000045) are a sequence where each element is the sum of the previous two elements. In the original Fibonacci sequence, the first two number are 1. So the sequence goes: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...`. For the challenge, we will accept any two numbers as the two starting numbers of the series.

### Ulam spiral

[The Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) is an arrangement of natural numbers. The spiral goes counter-clockwise and starts with the numbers `1, 2`, where the `2` is right of the `1`. For this exercise, only the shape of the spiral is relevant.

[image: Ulam spiral]

### Task

Find the length of the longest streak of generalised Fibonacci numbers (with any two starting numbers) following the Ulam spiral in a given array of integer numbers.

### Example

The following 5x5 array has two generalised Fibonacci sequences: one of length 4 (in blue + yellow: `138, 81, 219, 300`) and one of length 8 (in green + blue: `24, 57, 81, 138, 219, 357, 576, 933`). The answer is thus 8.

[image: Example]

### Rules

- Your program should at least support arrays up to 65535 * 65535 in size and array elements with values up to 4,294,967,295.
- Invalid input (non-square arrays, float or negative elements, non-arrays, etc.) may lead to unpredicted output, errors or (un)defined behaviour.
- [Default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply and [default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

***on question 1; see comments below***

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

***on question 2; see comments below***

- This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the fastest answer wins.
- Fastest code is measured in average user time over 5 different, undisclosed input matrices of sizes 100, 1000 and 10,000, each run 3 times on my late 2013 MacBook Pro with 2,3 GHz quadcore Intel i7 CPU and 16 GB of RAM.

### Review questions

- I plan on publishing this question twice: one time as a codegolf and one time as a fastest-code. See the last section of my question. I think this challenge has interesting but very different optimization strategies for speed and size. Is this be something that would be frowned upon by the CGSE community?
- Is the challenge clear enough as stated?
- Should I add more/larger test cases? Or a test case generating Python script?

Answer (score 0):

## Use the wrong paradigm

This is just a general idea, I don't know how you would go about scoring it or what the goal would be, but I think it would be fun to see stuff like oop in haskell.

Comment: Reminds me of [infix expression in Factor](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-infix.html) (it's funny because Factor is a stack-based language)

Answer (score 0):

## Perfect radicals

- Posted

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base)

[Perfect radicals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/215858/84844)

Answer (score 0):

[Posted to the main forum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216000/how-many-battleships-boards-are-there)

Comment: We do have occasional fastest code challenges, and many of them get great answers. For objective scoring, (unfortunately) it is necessary to score it on *your* machine because the specifics of OS/CPU/RAM/storage device/whatever can change the relative run time of two programs. One suggestion is to use smaller test cases (reduce board size and number of ships) so that programs can be tested without waiting for hours.

Comment: I can, for instance. set up a Linux virtual machine for the tests. And yes, it is possible to parameterise so as to have a scale of complexity: highest complexity gives authoritative score but lower ones used for weeding.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a valid board as the example and then a separate invalid one to illustrate that point.

Comment: @Xcali - good point. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Golfing on a Budget

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

### The Task

Every answer should take a positive number as input, and print/return every number in reverse down to zero (inclusive), in any reasonable format. For example:

```
10    -> "10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0"
8     -> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
1000  -> [["1", "0", "0", "0"], ["9", "9", "9"], ["9", "9", "8"], ...]
```

### The requirements

Every program has **$100** to spend.

The cost of each byte is determined by \$2^{t-1}\$, where \$t\$ is the number of times the byte has appeared in previous programs in addition to the current one.

For example, assuming it's the first program, `x->x++` would cost $10. Each `-` and `>` are $1, and each `x` and `+` are $2.

Comment: In some sense, doesn't this become a contest of speed to solution?  The earlier I post, the lower my score.  It also severely advantages certain languages that don't use ASCII.

Comment: Also, what's the criteria for winning?  What is the reason for the $100?

Comment: @Xcali This is currently a very rough idea, so I didn't have any winning criterion decided on yet. What I was trying to do was make it so that it would be harder to come up with valid answers as time went on, but I think the execution ended up really bad here.

Answer (score 0):

### Play the percussion for Ravel's Boléro

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

[image: rhythm]

The [Boléro](https://youtu.be/CJRE1y5uxOM?t=29) by Maurice Ravel is a piece of music characterised by a consistent snare drum pattern, repeated over and over, at unchanging tempo. This task is very challenging for a human performer, who must maintain the beat without rushing the tempo, or increasing the volume too quickly.

That's why you're going to write a program to do it!

I want your program to do *something* at the tempo and rhythm specified. It can output a key to a console, produce a beep, make a window pop up, have a graphical display flash colour; anything at all is acceptable, as long as it is A) observable to a human, and B) does not need human interaction for the program to continue. So if you make a pop-up, you should not require someone to click it away before the next pop-up can appear.

Using a tempo of 60 bpm (a bit slow but Ravel liked it played slowly), the whole rhythm takes exactly 6 seconds to play through. Here are the timings for when your program must send out some kind of signal, the unit being seconds. I'll tolerate divergences from the ideal of up to 0.02 seconds in either direction.

```
0.00
0.50
0.67
0.83
1.00
1.50
1.67
1.83
2.00
2.50
3.00
3.50
3.67
3.83
4.00
4.50
4.67
4.83
5.00
5.17
5.33
5.50
5.67
5.83
6.00
```

Note that here the final beat, at exactly 6 seconds, is the first beat of the next iteration of the rhythm; the next percussion hit occurs at 6.50, then 6.67, and 6.83, etcetera.

So, make your program produce that rhythm indefinitely. Choose whatever output you want. It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

---

For the sandboxers; I have considered using either this question as is, or having it be a popularity contest with added the stipulations that it ends after 170 repetitions and that the output somehow gradually gets *intenser* throughout that time, like the music does. The con is that popularity contests are a bit messier; but I would love to see creative ways to display the rhythm.

Comment: You should add an explanation for people who cannot read music; not everyone knows what a triplet is, or what `bpm` means.

Comment: @RobinRyder No knowledge of sheet music is needed; the picture is just illustrative. The list of timings is accurate.

Comment: The list of timings is accurate at 60 bpm, but not at other tempos.

Comment: @RobinRyder Very well, I will make 60 bpm the only accepted tempo and just have the timings be the final specification.

Answer (score 0):

## Simon says "Make me a game"

### [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Forked from [this closed question.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25014/create-a-simon-clone)

Create a "Simon says" game.

Take an input \$n\$, for number of levels, and \$k\$, for number of buttons and do the following:

- Create a square area for the buttons.(at least 100x100 pixels in size.)
- Divide it into k rectangular buttons of equal size. k will always be even.
- Each button should be of a different color, and none of them should be the same color as the background.
- The game should proceed as follows:

  - Starting level is 1. Level number should be displayed at the top.
  - Get a random order in which the buttons should "light up". The number of clicks should be level number + 4.
  - In that same sequence, display a visual indicator on each button, so the user knows what order they should click the buttons in.
  - There should be at least a 200ms delay between each visual indication.
  - If the user clicks them in the correct order, move on to the next level, and repeat the above steps. Otherwise, display "Game Over" at the bottom of the screen.

[Here is a playable demo for k=4](http://www.dantonag.it/miniSimon.html), Courtesy of [Gabriele D'Antona](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8685/gabriele-dantona).

---

## Meta

- Is this specification clear?
- Any thoughts/feedback?
- Should there be a limit on the values of n and k?

Answer (score 0):

## [Animal-Alphabetical Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216555/animal-alphabetical-sequence)

Comment: Seems like a cool challenge except for the part where you have to start from the googolth element. I'd suggest starting from the beginning instead.

Comment: Also, JAMBU won't appear anywhere in the output since none of the other animals have Js in them. Same for ZEBRA and maybe others. You might consider choosing different animal names, dropping your 5-letter theme, and ensuring that all 26 letters can possibly exist in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

### Answers made up from older answers

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

---

In this challenge, your task is to take a number as input, and determine whether it is the number of previous answers. For example, the third answer would print/return a truthy value is given `2`, and a falsey value for any other input.

However, all answers must be made up of previous answers. For example, if the existing answers were `+1`, `t()==1`, and `_=>inpu`, some allowed answers would be:

- `t()==1+1`
- `_=>input()==1+1`
- `+1+1+1+1`
- `​`

Examples of answers that would not be allowed:

- `1+`
- `1+1`
- `_=>+1`
- ```
  ​
  ```

  (newline)

For the output/return format, [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19266/79857) is a list of the allowed formats I'll use for this challenge.

*Scoring and initial allowed parts of answers coming soon.*

### Meta

- What should the title be?
- Any recommended initial allowed parts?
- Is this easy to read/understand?

Comment: This is understandable, and seems to make a fun challenge. You should probably restrict having the same language twice (although i'm assuming that's implied) because that would make it boring. The title could be like "Answer Recycling" or something, but I'm not very creative with titles.

Comment: @GioD Oh, I forgot about that, I'll make sure to add that restriction. Thanks for the title suggestion, too!

Comment: No problem, I just like the idea of recycling being used in a problem. Are people allowed to submit more than once? because this definitely seems like a fun challenge. My idea of a first program would just be "0" in retina, but that seems like it wouldn't make for a lot of creativity

Comment: @GioD I'd probably just restrict posting more than one answer in a row. Glad to see there's some interest in this challenge!

Comment: My idea for initial characters were "0", "1", " ", newline, and "=" although that might not work as well as I think it would. I'd recommend experimenting, since I'm fairly new to code golfing and i don't know most of the languages out there.

Comment: I don't see how the parts list gets expanded with each answer.  If it doesn't, how do different answers get created?

Comment: @Xcali That's an issue I was thinking about, I think my solution will be allowing each answer to add one new part. For example, if the current parts are `a`, `bc`, and `d`, I could answer `abcfdabc`, so the new parts list would be `a`, `bc`, `d`, `abcfdabc`

Answer (score 0):

### Implement ASCII -> GSM-7 (SMS) text packing

SMS messages can store 160 ASCII characters into 140 characters. It does this by chopping off the top bit from each byte and packing them together.

The simplified steps:

1. Convert the string to binary little endian ASCII.
2. Remove the top bit from each byte.
3. Pack them together so there are no gaps.
4. If applicable, pad the final byte with zero bits.

So, take the text "Test0123".

First, we convert it to little endian binary.

```
0x54     0x65     0x73     0x74     0x30     0x31     0x32     0x33
00101010 10100110 11001110 00101110 00001100 10001100 01001100 11001100
```

Then, we chop off the last (most significant) bit of each octet:

```
0010101  1010011  1100111  0010111  0000110  1000110  0100110  1100110
```

Then, we pack them together into a 7 byte array:

```
0xd4     0xf2     0x9c     0x0e     0x8b     0xc9     0x66
00101011 01001111 00111001 01110000 11010001 10010011 01100110
```

In the case of bitwise operations, it is a simple funnel shift.

The basic algorithm in C is here for an 8 byte ASCII string. However, your algorithm must accept any length.

```c
void ascii_to_gsm7_8_bytes(uint8_t *buf, const char *str)
{
    buf[0] = (str[0] >> 0) | (str[1] << 7);
    buf[1] = (str[1] >> 1) | (str[2] << 6);
    buf[2] = (str[2] >> 2) | (str[3] << 5);
    buf[3] = (str[3] >> 3) | (str[4] << 4);
    buf[4] = (str[4] >> 4) | (str[5] << 3);
    buf[5] = (str[5] >> 5) | (str[6] << 2);
    buf[6] = (str[6] >> 6) | (str[7] << 1);
}
```

The input can either be a string (optionally with a provided length) or an input from stdin which is terminated with a newline or EOF.

The string will be a non-empty printable ASCII string that is 160 bytes or less. It is safe to assume that all bytes are 0x20 <= x < 0x80, meaning the last MSB bit is cleared beforehand.

**Important:** While strings can be null terminated, you are **not** allowed to use that null terminator for padding the last byte.

Output will be the packed string.

The output can either be printed as a list of values (base 10 or base 16) to stdout or returned in an output array.

Test cases (output is in hex):

```c
Input text -> Output (hex)
"" -> Empty strings do not need to be handled.
"Úñíçódé" -> Unicode does not need to be handled, only ASCII.
"Hi!" -> {0xc8, 0x74, 0x08}
"Test0123" -> {0xd4, 0xf2, 0x9c, 0x0e, 0x8b, 0xc9, 0x66}
```

More test cases will be added if this is accepted.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes per language wins.

Comment: You should probably provide example input/outputs for so that it's easy for people to test their program and to get a grasp of what the program is asking.

Comment: I updated the rules to make them more clear, removed the 140 byte requirement, and added an example and a few test cases

Comment: 1. Bonuses to a score are generally frowned upon.  2. I'm confused about the output format.  What is needed?  3. Why the null requirement added to the end?  I don't see that in the SMS spec.  4. What's the winning criteria?

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

## Isosceles triangle truncations

Most triangles are not isosceles. Here is an example:

```
A ____ C
 |   /
E|  /
 | /D
 |/
B
```

However, we can cut this triangle into two smaller triangles, one of which is isosceles. We can do this in a number of ways:

- By cutting from C to E, we create isosceles triangle BEC. (Due to limitations of ASCII art, you'll just have to imagine that E is in the correct place.)
- By cutting from A to D, we create isosceles triangle ADB.
- By cutting from A to D, we create isosceles triangle ADC. (This always happens for right-angled triangles, of course. It's hard to draw ASCII art triangles that are neither right-angled nor isosceles.)

Each triangle can be derived in turn from the original triangle by fixing one of the three sides (which will be the base of the new triangle) and the smaller of the two adjacent angles, adjusting the other base angle as necessary.

Your challenge is, given a triangle of three points A, B and C in any reasonable format, is to output at least one of its isosceles triangle truncations.

It must be possible to obtain all three truncations for a given triangle. This is typically achieved by permuting the parameters of the function, but you can use some other input method if you wish. In any case please indicate how to obtain all truncations.

Example: For an input of (0, 0), (0, 4) and (8, 0), the output might be (0, 0), (4, 2), (8, 0); (0, 0), (0, 4), (4, 2); (3, 0), (0, 4), (8, 0). Alternatively, the output might just be (3, 0), and to obtain (4, 2) you would have to input the triangle in a different order.

You may assume that the input triangle is not isosceles (or equilateral, for those languages that allow parameters that are surds rather than floating-point decimals). For instance, for programs that normally output all truncations, they might simply return a single equilateral triangle unchanged.

Your method should be theoretically exact even if the code suffers from floating-point limitations.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Your Challenge

Find out if a function **always** returns its input.

## Input/Output Information

Input is a math expression as a string with operators `+ - ( ) /`.
The multiplication symbol is `*`, or `x` if you specify.

The input will always will only contain <s>whitespace</s> spaces, decimal points, numbers (`0123456789`), math symbols (`+ - ( ) /` and one of the following: `*` or `x`) and one lowercase letter that is the variable.

Whitespace in the input must be ignored.

Output is whether the function will **always** return its input.

The expression will never have a division by a polynomial with its degree >1.
Example: `x*x*x/x*x` <= this will never be input.

## Example Input/Output

```
Input: n /3 + 2*n/3 + 175 - 175*(n+ 1-n)
Output: truthy
Explain: Simplifies to "n"

Input: f
Output: truthy
Explain: Any variable is allowed

Input: j*(j-3.1)/(j-   3.1)
Output: falsey
Explain: In normal math, this evaluates to j
However, when j is 3.1, it is undefined
Therefore, it doesn’t ALWAYS return its input
This is because when j is 3.1, the output is not 3.1

Input: 1j
Output: truthy
Explain: 1j = j which is the input

Input: n/2 + n/2
Output: truthy
Explain: Simplifies to 2n/2 = n which is the input
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest amount of bytes wins!

### Sandbox Questions

I brought this back from a long time ago.

Any unaddressed problems?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Comment: There's some inconsistency in the examples: the first one is being treated as if it's a maths expression whereas the third one is not. Suppose the input is `n/2 + n/2`. Should the output be true? In [some languages](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P03BVkHXLq86T99IQVsBSNZypSOE9AwggnoGtVy5QGEjrjwgaYwOuApKS4oV0qJzYxVsbRVyYdw8MDcPwk1HlU2Hyf7/DwA "Ruby – Try It Online") the output will *not* necessarily be the same as the input: `/` might get you floor division or conversion to 
a float. You can avoid these issues by treating the input as maths. But in that case, example 3 should simplify to `j`.

Comment: Why is there an `x` in your first test case? Right now it'll become `n-175(x-1)` (`n/3+2*n/3` becomes `n` and `175-175x(n+1-n)` becomes `-175(x-1)`).. I assume that `x` either should be gone or a `*`? Also, you may want to clarify what's in the input. You mention `+-*/` and whitespaces, but all the lowercase letters and parenthesis aren't mentioned anywhere. And assuming that first test case was a mistake, is the input guaranteed to not contain more than one unique lowercase letter?

Comment: Thanks @KevinC, I clarified that just now

Comment: Looks good, +1 from me. As for the `*`/`x`, I would just put the `*` in the string with the other operators, and just mention something like "if your language is using a different operator character (i.e. `x` instead of `*`), you are allowed to use it instead. If you're unsure whether a character is allowed, leave a comment.", or something along those lines. The operator characters used aren't too relevant for the core of the challenge, and some languages might use `*`/`x`/`×`/`·` for multiplication or `/`/`÷` for division. Or just `ASMD` for add/subtract/multiplication/division.

Comment: Then again, most answers will probably do something along the lines of: replace the lowercase letter with the input; eval; check if it equals the input. 

Comment: No, that wouldn’t work because `n*n/n`, or maybe `n*((n+149485)/(n+149485))`

Comment: What would be the domain and range of these mathematical functions?

Comment: Depends **which** mathematical function you are talking about…?

Answer (score 0):

## possible chess moves in choice format

[chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)
the goal is to make a function that takes in a board in choice format and color and outputs all possible moves.

for example: `['pawn',1,1] -> ['pawn',1,2], ['pawn',1,3]`.

Comment: Glad to see you took my advice and posted this here. I don't think fastest code is a good winning criterion - a queen on a central square has a maximum of 27 moves available to her, so even with 16 unrestricted queens (an impossible situation) a player would have 432 moves, which would be solvable instantly in most languages. I would suggest codegolf as a winning criterion

Comment: I suggest you develop this with: 1. full definition of input and output format 2. Consideration of the following: do we have to consider castling, double square advance for unmoved pawns, en passant? 3. Do we have to consider pawn promotion, and does promotion to different pieces (a queen or knight for example) count as a different move? 4. What pieces can a player be expected to have? a) the normal 16 at the start of the game, b) the normal 16 after some/all pawns have been promoted c) some more  bizarre set of pieces? 5. Should moves leaving king in check be included / excluded from output?

Comment: Suggested input format: White pieces `RNBKQ and P`, black pieces `rnbkq and p` on an 8x8 grid. By the way welcome to the site.

Comment: I recommend you look through the existing chess questions and make this one sufficiently different. Here's a couple I've seen before (and answered one of them) but then forgot about https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45179/15599 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89429/15599

Comment: Are chess libraries allowed?

Comment: @Razetime no, chess libraries are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Divisor chains

### Definition

A simple path in the divisor graph of `{1,...,n}` is a
sequence of distinct numbers between `1` and `n` such that
if `k` immediately follows `m`, then either `k` divides `m`
or `m` divides `k`.

### Task

(1) Return a list of integers that represents the
lexicographically earliest longest, simple path in the
divisor graph of `{1,...,n}`.

Implement a named function with one argument, `f(n)`, `n` a
positive integer; you can assume `n <= 33`. The function
takes the argument for input.

No print statements (or other I/O-statements) are allowed in
the function; the return is a list (or tuple or array).
The use of external library functions is not allowed.

(2) A print statement that prints the output of (1):
`print(f(n))`. The function name `print` is not obligatory
and the print function can use standard libraries.

### Test

(1) For `n = 10` the call `f(10)` returns
`[4, 8, 1, 5, 10, 2, 6, 3, 9]`.

(2) `print(f(10))`. We do not fix the format of the returned
list. The output might also look like `4 8 1 5 10 2 6 3 9`
or any other convenient way.

### Challenge

This is code-golf with restricted-time, so the shortest code in
bytes wins if it can run the test above on TIO https://tio.run/
without timing out. Only the code of the generating function
f is counted, without the print statement.

Tags: code-golf, restricted-time, math, sequence

Answer (score 0):

## Lazy Robot Monkey Problem

### Question Summary

You have made a robot monkey. The purpose of the robot is to move through the trees and try to reach as many as possible monkeys before running out of battery. You have to follow some rules while moving.

You are give a interlinked tree in the following format :

[image]

Here each 1 is a monkey and each 0 is an empty place.

Each note can have multiple parents and Childs but unlike a Graph its direction is downward.

The robot monkey has a initial energy value.

The robot Monkey can  move through the nodes following certain rules:

- Going up to the parent node needs 4 units energy.
- Going down to the child node needs 2 units energy.
- There may be some food at some nodes. Each times the monkey eats its energy increases by food value.
- The monkeys energy can never be negative.
- The monkey cannot eat more than the initial energy value.

### What to do?

You are given the initial node (where your robot monkey is initially sitting).

The node is in the following format :

```
class Node:
    parents = [] # Will have all the parents
    children = [] # Will have all the children
    isMonkey = 1 # May be 0
    foodValue = 0 # May be anything
```

You are also given a initial food value and the number of monkeys in the tree.

You now have to find how many monkeys can you maximum meet with  before your battery dies.(by going to the same position)

Your answer should be in format:

```
def monkeyMeet(initialNode, energy, totalMonkeys):
    # write your code here
    pass
```

Or in any other programming language.

The size of the tree may be huge.

Comment: Is this code golf? You need to have a way to have entries be compared (within a language).

Answer (score 0):

## Radical of an integer [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The radical of an integer (written as \$\mathrm{rad}(n)\$) is defined as the product of all prime numbers that divide it. This it [A007947](https://oeis.org/A007947).

For example, since \$ 504 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \$, \$ \mathrm{rad}(504) = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 = 42 \$.

## Challenge

Your task is to write a function or a program which takes a number as the input, and output its radical.

- You can take/output the numbers in any format allowed by [the default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

You don't have to handle any cases where the input isn't an integer or isn't positive (you don't have to handle 0).

### Test cases:

```
504 -> 42
6 -> 6
57 -> 57
1024 -> 2
9 -> 3
1 -> 1
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Good Luck!

Comment: I think you can omit the "input/output in any base" part ("the output base must match the input base" is especially unnecessary) and let the answers use any sensible, consistent integer I/O as allowed in our defaults. Other than that, nice challenge.

Comment: Suggested test case: `1 -> 1`.

Comment: What is the behaviour for negative numbers and zero?

Comment: @pxeger `You don't have to handle any cases where the input isn't an integer or isn't positive (you don't have to handle 0).`

Comment: @CommandMaster whoops, missed that

Comment: This is [A007947](https://oeis.org/A007947), which describes it as "Largest squarefree number dividing n".

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120078/66833)

Comment: Dang, I should stop using built-in SE search for finding duplicates.

Comment: @Bubbler I was pretty sure I recognized the challenge, it was xnor's comment that lead me to it (searched "squarefree number is:q")

Answer (score 0):

## SimpleHearts KOTH

### SimpleHearts

SimpleHearts is a four player trick-taking card game similar to Hearts, with a few simplifications. Hearts has several possible rule variations, and the rules I will use are outlined here.

For each game, each of the four players are dealt 13 of the cards in a standard deck. After that, there will be 13 "tricks", and during each trick the players will take turns playing exactly one of their cards. Each trick will consist of the following:

- One player leads the trick by playing a card. The suit of this card is the "led suit". On the first trick the player with the 2 of clubs must lead with the 2 of clubs, on the following tricks whoever won the previous trick will lead.

  The leader may not lead a heart until another player has played a heart or the Qs (Queen of Spades). Exception: if the leader only has hearts in their hand, they may lead one of their hearts. The leader may lead the Qs at any time.
- In a clockwise fashion, each player will take their turn playing one card in their hand of the led suit. If the player has no cards of the led suit, they may play *any* card. Exception: On the very first trick, no one after the leader may play a heart or the Qs, unless all of their cards are hearts or the Qs (obviously absurdly unlikely).
- After all four players play a card, whichever player played the highest value card of the led suit wins the trick. Ace is highest value and 2 is lowest. The winner of the trick receives 1 point for every heart played by anyone in the trick, and 13 points if the Qs was played in the trick.
- Repeat, with the winner leading the next trick.

The objective of the game is to receive as *few* points as possible. After all 13 tricks are played, the score of each player is the total number of points they took during gameplay. Important exception: if one player takes all possible points, i.e. the 13 hearts *and* the Qs, they receive 0 points and all other players receive 26 points (this is called "shooting the moon").

Key differences from standard Hearts:

- There is no passing cards
- Scores are not cumulative in the standard way (the scoring system of this particular challenge will be explained next).

### Gameplay and Scoring

This is a KOTH challenge, meaning the objective is to create a bot (in this case a Python function) which will compete against other submitted bots in the game of SimpleHearts. All  subsets of size 4 of the set of submissions will play against each other in N matches of 4 games each. **For sandbox: N is tbd, should be as high as reasonably possible.**

The dealing of the cards will be identical in each of the 4 games in a match, except rotated. For example, suppose the players are A, B, C, and D. In the second game player B will have the same hand player A had in game 1, C will have B's game 1 hand, etc. This is to reduce the impact of random chance, as one player being dealt a bad hand will affect all players equally in theory.

Each submission's final score will be the sum of their scores in all the games they played. The winner will be the submission with the lowest final score. In the case of a tie, the oldest submission will win.

### Technical Requirements

Each submission will be a Python function **(for sandbox: this is an arbitrary choice, is there a better one?)** which takes as parameters:

- A list of 2-tuples representing the cards in their hand. Each tuple will be of the form `(12, 's')` with the number representing the value of the suit and the string representing the suit, being one of `s, h, d, c`. For simplicity's sake the numbers are from 2 to 14, and we do not care about encoding "Queen" or "Ace". Therefore the Queen of Spades is `(12, 's')`, Ace of Diamonds is `(14, 'd')`, and the 2 of clubs is `(2, 'c')`.
- A list of 4 integers representing the scores of each player so far in the current game. The first element of the list is your score, then the player to your left, then the player across, then the player to your right.

  Note: leading with hearts is allowed if and only if you only have hearts, or someone has a nonzero score.
- A list of 4 lists of tuples representing which cards have been played and by whom. The first list will be the cards you played, in order. The second list will be the cards played by the player on your left, in order. Etc.
- A list of 0-3 tuples representing the cards that have been played in the trick, in order.

As output, the submission must return a single tuple representing a card in its hand, which is legal to play according to the rules of SimpleHearts. Of course, the function may choose to ignore any of these inputs but if it makes an illegal output, it is disqualified. In testing, I will force whoever has the 2 of clubs to lead with it on the first hand, ignoring the contents of the function.

The submission must be deterministic, i.e. will always produce the same output on the same input (so pseudorandom numbers with a set seed are allowed).

All submissions must be at most 100 000 characters.

The challenge will end 14 days after this prompt is posted, after which I will test all valid submissions against each other in the manner I described.

### For sandbox

This prompt is still WIP, but I appreciate any comments. I intend to create a controller and some example submissions, but only after Sandbox folk deem the challenge to be good enough.

Is there any reasonable way to make the requirements easier or the game simpler? Cause this post is kinda long.

Comment: 1. You should probably forbid tampering with the environment/other bots. 2. You probably should clarify what happens if a bot throws an exception, and what happens during a disqualification (do the round with the disqualified bot simply not count or does a dummy bot come into play) 3.  There is nothing wrong with a python function but it is worth noting that most koth competitions are either a JS function or a Java abstract class. 4. Also, it might be worth adding some sort of timeout for the bots.

Comment: So you're not playing with the rule that if one player wins all 124 points, then their score changes to 0 and the other players get 124 each instead? The risk there the most fun part of hearts!

Comment: @pxeger I'm not sure what you mean. I did mention shooting the moon, but what do you mean winning all 124 points?

Comment: @79037662 I missed that because I've never heard it described as "shooting the moon". 124 is the sum of the available points in the scoring system I know (2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+10(J)+10(Q)+10(K)+15(A)+25(QS))

Comment: @pxeger In the standard ruleset, all hearts are worth 1 each and QS is worth 13 :)

Answer (score 0):

## The UTM theorem

Let `ℕ` denote the set of [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Let `A × B` denote the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `A` and `B`. Let `A ⇀ B` denote the set of [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) from `A` to `B`.

The [UTM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_theorem) says that there exists a [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) `u : ℕ × ℕ ⇀ ℕ` such that, for every computable function `f : ℕ ⇀ ℕ`, there exists a `p : ℕ` such that, for every `x : ℕ`, `u(p, x) ≃ f(x)`. That is, there exists a *universal* computable function (analogous to the [universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_turing_machine)).

Implement such a function in your language. Shorter is better.

### Example: Python (57 chars)

```
lambda p,x:eval(p.to_bytes(p.bit_length()//8+1,'big'))(x)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can emulate a while loop in Python eval?

Comment: Also, this has the same problem as [your other sandboxed challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20663/78410) in that eval does the job in many languages.

Comment: @Bubbler It should be able to emulate (some variant of) the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), which requires only pure functions.

Answer (score 0):

## Write a Brainfuck compiler + decompiler!

Many Brainfuck compilers will convert to a different language instead of compiling directly.

Your job is to write not only a compiler in language X which compiles Brainfuck to the **same language as the compiler**, but also a **decompiler** which takes code compiled with said compiler and **outputs equivalent Brainfuck.**

### Rules

- No embedding the original/stripped source code or similar loopholes. **You know what I mean.**

  - Additionally, no outputting an interpreter with the original source code.
- The compiler must accept whitespace and comments
- Optimizations are allowed and encouraged, as long as you can convert these *back* to Brainfuck.
- The input will always be a valid Brainfuck program
- You are not required to print comments in the decompiler, however, excess comments and whitespace are allowed in the output as long as the program is valid. However, these lower your score.
- You do not need to handle excess whitespace or comments in the decompiler, **you can assume it was code directly generated by your compiler.**

  - Therefore, it is also guaranteed to be valid code.
- No executing the compiled code.
- The compiler must generate correct code and run without any helpers.

  - You are allowed to be flexible with the cell size as long as it is at least 8 bits.
  - You are allowed to be flexible with the tape size as long as it is at least 30,000 elements. A wrapping tape is not required.
  - EOF can store either 0, -1, or leave unchanged

Your score will be the following:

(compiler size in bytes + decompiler size in bytes) × ([compiled size of factor.bf in bytes](https://github.com/fabianishere/brainfuck/blob/b131824561e155a8708a0f5b78a5e6736f6aba3e/examples/math/factor.bf) ÷ size of factor.bf in bytes)

This is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so **the most votes wins.** This is because there can be some creative and boring solutions. Golfing is still encouraged.

Comment: Couldn't there be multiple BF programs that compile to the same "byte code" due to optimisations?

Comment: Good catch. I added a note about that. I emphasized that you are decompiling YOUR code, and optimizations are not required, and if you do add optimizations, they must decompile to the same code (so basically, don't optimize if you want to win )

Comment: Am I allowed to add hints in my code that identify what the original BF was?

Comment: Hmm..yeah that is kind of difficult to rule out. I am going to change it to include the size of the code output in the score to discourage it.

Comment: So is the total score the size of the compiler plus the size of the decompiler? Can they be a single program doing both?

Comment: Any restrictions on what target languages are allowed?

Comment: So am I understanding it right that the compiler and the target language must be identical?

Comment: Can the decompiler be a macro? Also, I know it's not recommended often, but this wouldn't be too bad as a popularity challenge.

Comment: Should the cells be wrapping or not?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to support comments without embedding them into the code.

Comment: I mean that your compiler must accept comments, but it is not required to preserve them. I also made some of the changes suggested in the comments

Comment: Can we have EOF as no change? That's a somewhat common way of handling EOF

Comment: Note that if it's too hard then it won't be popular anyway. (writing an optimizing compiler alone is a very difficult task, and who would read that?)

Comment: Still not quite understand about what "embedding" means here. The program translated / synthesized is required to include what the source code do. So it will always embedding the source code by some how. Is it valid if I simply replace `+-<>[],.` by `01234567` and then convert it back? May I simply submit a brainf**k (or bf variance) program say `,[.,]`?

Comment: Yeah I should try to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

## Cosmic ray hacking

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

Cosmic background radiation can cause random bit flips in electronics. For this reason, some mission-critical computers
undergo [radiation hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening). Your task is to use your magic bit
flip gun to hack in to a program and make it print something different.

### Cops' challenge

- Write a program or function that outputs a determinate, non-empty string of your choice (which you should specify).
- Choose a different, determinate string of your choice (which you should specify).
- Also specify a number `n` which is the number of bit flips the robbers should perform on your answer in order to get
  it to output the second string.

#### Rules

- [Standard IO rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest uncracked program wins.

### Robbers' challenge

Choose an uncracked cop submission written by another user. Find a program that differs by exactly `n` bit flips from
the original cop's program, and outputs the string `s` (where `n` and `s` are specified by the cop). First valid crack
for each cop answer wins.

#### Rules

- Your program must be written in the same language and version as the cop's
- Your program must use the same I/O method as the cop's, unless they specify otherwise
- Flipping the same bit twice (which does nothing to the whole string) is allowed, but it takes up 2 of your available
  bit flips.

### Example

#### Cops - Python 3, 8 bytes

Prints `5`.

```
print(5)
```

Using 1 bit flip, change this program to print `4`.

#### Robbers - Cracks example answer

```
print(4)
```

Because the ASCII digit `5` is `00110101`, and `4` is `00110100` (the last bit has been flipped)

---

## Meta

- Should I change the scoring system?
- This is related to [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening), but I don't think it actually is. Is this
  right? Or maybe [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) or [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) would be better? ([radiation-softening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-softening)?)
- [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) refers to the limit that the cop imposes on the robber, rather than the scoring system - is this an acceptable use of the tag?
- Is this clear enough?
- Is this a duplicate of an existing challenge?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: How are cops' answers scored?

Comment: @thedefault. [tag:code-golf]; it's in the cops' rules section

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

This challenge was originally the ["Among Us"](https://github.com/ChocolateOverflow/Writeup-YASCON_CTF_2020/tree/master/Misc/Among_us) challenge in the "Misc" category of YASCON CTF 2020. (The link includes an answer to that challenge. Click at your own risk.)

You're given a lot of files, only 1 of which is different from every other files. Your job is to find that 1 different file.

## Challenge

- Input: the file names of all the files to be searched through.
- Output: the name of the 1 different file.

Avoid burying the important details of your challenge in a mound of unimportant details. Be concise. Include what needs to be included.

It is guaranteed to have $n+1$ files, of which $n \ge 2$ files are the exact same, and 1 different file.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Least bytes wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 1.txt 2.jpg 3.png 4.mp3

Output:

(`3.png` is different)

> 3.png

Comment: 'Answer the following questions for your readers . . . Avoid burying the important details of your challenge in a mound of unimportant details. Be concise. Include what needs to be included.' This is what *you* are supposed to do as the challenge writer, not part of the spec.

Comment: Do you have permission to repost this challenge here?

Comment: Well  I got permission to upload the challenge and its files anywhere from that CTF, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a playable, unbeatable Tic Tac Toe game

The challenge is to write the smallest possible Tic Tac Toe game where the opponent is an unbeatable AI. The requirements are as follows:

- The opponent should be an unbeatable AI (self-playing opponent that can't lose)
- The game should be able to detect win/draw/loss and end if this happens (without crashing)
- The input should be the player move (square index or something like that)
- The game should be able to handle invalid input and act appropriate if this happens (ask for input again)
- The game must be displayed graphically on a classic 3x3 format with X:s, O:s and empty squares. The display should be in line vertically and horizontally, se below examples. The display needs to happen after at least every human move to be able to follow the progress.

As long as these conditions are fulfilled you are free to solve it in any way you'd like.

**Rules of Tic Tac Toe:** Each player (X and O) takes turn placing their marker on the 3x3 board. The game ends in a win if the player gets 3 in a row, loss if opponent gets 3 in a row, and draws if the board gets full.

**Challenge winning criterion:** Smallest code in bytes.

**Example view of a valid input/output gameplay:**

```
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']

Your move: 3
[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']

[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', 'O', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']

Your move: 6
[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', 'O', 'X']
[' ', ' ', ' ']

[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', 'O', 'X']
[' ', ' ', 'O']

Your move: 8
[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', 'O', 'X']
[' ', 'X', 'O']

['O', ' ', 'X']
[' ', 'O', 'X']
[' ', 'X', 'O']
```

**Example of invalid gameplay (not horizontally or vertically in line and not using X and O as markers, which makes it hard to see what is going on):**

```
Your move: 4
[, , ]
[0, , ]
[, , ]

[1, , ]
[0, , ]
[, , ]

Your move: 9
[1, , ]
[0, , ]
[, , 0]
```

**Suggested tags:** tic-tac-toe, code-golf

Comment: Good draft. Now you're well on the way to a properly specified challenge. Thank you for using the sandbox!

Comment: I assume that by "graphically" you include e.g. text-based in a console. You might want to make that clear.

Comment: Who makes the first move?

Comment: Thanks, updated. I don't udnerstand what you mean with the text based comment though. I feel like this thing is getting worse than writing for some government, really killing the joy to be honest.

Comment: It *is* stricter than government writings; the latter can be vague and instead rely on the courts to disambiguate later. We don't have that luxury here. But while painful for the challenge writer, it is exactly what makes it enjoyable for the challenge *answerer*. I *highly* recommend that you answer a few existing challenges before attempting the, frankly monumental, task of writing your own. This will give you an appreciation for well-specified challenges. I've been here for years, and have an order of magnitude more answers than challenges, and yes, my early challenges were problematic too.

Comment: Updated with tags and winning criterion

Comment: Suggested tags (remember that the max is 5): [tag:interactive], [tag:game], [tag:board-game], [tag:grid], [tag:ai-player].

Comment: I'd suggest paring down this challenge to what I think is the most interesting part, making the unbeatable AI. That is, just require writing a function/program that takes in a single game state and outputs an optimal move, without needing to handle the game flow.

Comment: @xnor, that could also be an idea!

Comment: @Adám, could I try that or xnors idea in the real questions thread now?

Comment: @eligolf I like xnor's idea, as game flow as already been done before, e.g. [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24134/43319). However, I generally recommend allowing at least a week in the sandbox (wait for a couple of upvotes here) since some people visit the site on a weekly schedule (e.g. only on weekends, or only during work). It's code golf ― what's the rush? If, after a week, you've not gotten enough feedback here, consider asking for more feedback in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: I found a similar challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152064/20260

Answer (score 0):

## Ratios to Ben Johnston's Notation

[music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a just intonation ratio, express it as a note name in [Ben Johnston's notation](https://www.kylegann.com/BJNotation.html) relative to C.

You can take your input as a rational number (if your language has a rational type) or as a pair of integers. You have to handle ratios with a prime limit of 19, or in other words, ratios whose prime factorizations don't contain any primes above 19.

Use the following characters for the accidentals:

```
+ - 81/80
# b 25/24
7 L 35/36
^ v 33/32
13 _13 65/64
17 _17 51/50
19 _19 95/96
```

Output them in the following order:

- `7`, `^`, `13`, `17`, `19`
- `#`, `b`
- `L`, `v`, `_13`, `_17`, `_19`
- `+`, `-`

`7`, `13`, `17`, and `19` should be separated by commas when they occur adjacently in order to avoid ambiguity.

Test cases:

```
1/1 -> C
2/1 -> C
3/2 -> G
4/3 -> F
5/4 -> E
5/3 -> A
6/5 -> Eb
7/4 -> B7b
7/5 -> G7b
9/5 -> Bb
9/8 -> D
10/9 -> D-
11/8 -> F^
16/9 -> Bb+
17/16 -> C17#
21/16 -> F7+
25/24 -> C#
32/27 -> Eb-
34/19 -> A17_19#
78/77 -> C13Lv
81/64 -> E+
160/147 -> C#LL-
323/280 -> D17,19L-
416/405 -> D13bb-
441/440 -> Db7v+
1029/1024 -> Db777+
6144/6125 -> CbLL-
531441/524288 -> B#+++
4194304/4117715 -> A#LLLLLLL---
```

Comment: Same issue as the other challenge, I didn't read the link and the question is not self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

## Find all enharmonic equivalences of an arbitrary EDO

[music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given integers *n* and *s*, print all pairs of [enharmonically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic) [pitch classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_class) in *n*-[EDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament), such that each note of a pair has at most *s* sharps and flats.

Note names are assigned such that F, C, G, D, A, E, and B form a chain of *n*-EDO's best approximation to 3/2 (that is, \$n \log_2(3/2)\$ steps, rounded to the nearest integer, or the "fifth"). "#" adds seven fifths, and "b" subtracts seven fifths; you can have as many of one as you want or none at all. (Note that in some EDOs, such as 24, there are some pitches that can't be written with only sharp and flat accidentals.)

Note that `C# = Db` means the same thing as `Db = C#`. Your code should output only one of these, but which one you output is up to you.

Be prepared to handle these situations:

- `#` and `b` might not raise or lower the pitch
- `#` might *lower* the pitch
- E and F might be the same note
- F might be lower than E

Your code should work for at least all integers *n* in [1, 200] and all integers *s* in [0, 50].

### Test output

(12, 1)

```
F# = Gb
Fb = E
F = E#
C# = Db
Cb = B
C = B#
G# = Ab
D# = Eb
A# = Bb
```

(19, 1)

```
Fb = E#
Cb = B#
```

(19, 2)

```
F# = Gbb
F## = Gb
Fbb = E
Fb = E#
F = E##
C# = Dbb
C## = Db
Cbb = B
Cb = B#
C = B##
G# = Abb
G## = Ab
D# = Ebb
D## = Eb
A# = Bbb
A## = Bb
```

(22, 2)

```
Fbb = C#
Fb = C##
F## = Bbb
Cbb = G#
Cb = G##
Gbb = D#
Gb = D##
Dbb = A#
Db = A##
Abb = E#
Ab = E##
Ebb = B#
Eb = B##
```

(31, 3)

```
Fbbb = D#
Fbb = D##
Fb = D###
F## = Abbb
F### = Abb
Cbbb = A#
Cbb = A##
Cb = A###
C## = Ebbb
C### = Ebb
Gbbb = E#
Gbb = E##
Gb = E###
G## = Bbbb
G### = Bbb
Dbbb = B#
Dbb = B##
Db = B###
```

(32, 3)

```
F## = Dbbb
F### = Dbb
Fbbb = A#
Fbb = A##
Fb = A###
C## = Abbb
C### = Abb
Cbbb = E#
Cbb = E##
Cb = E###
G## = Ebbb
G### = Ebb
Gbbb = B#
Gbb = B##
Gb = B###
D## = Bbbb
D### = Bbb
```

(53, 4)

```
F#### = Dbbbb
Fbbbb = A###
Fbbb = A####
C#### = Abbbb
Cbbbb = E###
Cbbb = E####
G#### = Ebbbb
Gbbbb = B###
Gbbb = B####
D#### = Bbbbb
```

(5, 0)

```
F = E
C = B
```

(7, 1)

```
Fb = F
Fb = F#
F = F#
Cb = C
Cb = C#
C = C#
Gb = G
Gb = G#
G = G#
Db = D
Db = D#
D = D#
Ab = A
Ab = A#
A = A#
Eb = E
Eb = E#
E = E#
Bb = B
Bb = B#
B = B#
```

(9, 1)

```
Fb = G
F = G#
Fb = A#
F# = Eb
Cb = D
C = D#
Cb = E#
C# = Bb
Gb = A
G = A#
Gb = B#
Db = E
D = E#
Ab = B
A = B#
```

(11, 1)

```
F# = Db
Fb = A
F = A#
C# = Ab
Cb = E
C = E#
G# = Eb
Gb = B
G = B#
D# = Bb
```

(13, 1)

```
F# = Cb
Fb = B
F = B#
C# = Gb
G# = Db
D# = Ab
A# = Eb
E# = Bb
```

Comment: I think most people prefer that questions should not include background knowledge that not most people know without explanation.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about reducing the amount of background knowledge required and making the question more accessible?

Comment: I didn't read it...

Answer (score 0):

## [Implement bottom (encode)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218572/implement-bottom-encode)

Comment: The general policy is to provide an explanation for concepts that most people don't know inside the question itself. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 Is this better?

Comment: Suggested test case: invalid utf8, invalid surrogate,  empty string,  some char with unicode value > 0x10000, combined emoji, combining mark in unicode.

Comment: Generally people don't like things like "must take input on stdin, must take output on stdout, must take input in UTF8 encoding, must check for invalid UTF8, must return exit code 1". You can still keep it, but I did warn you.

Comment: I removed the full program requirement and the UTF-8 validation so there also shouldn’t be any need for an exit code. I also added some more test cases and a rule on an empty string

Comment: Since I don't have emoji font installed, you can include a textual explanation on the input/output pairs. (like `AB (byte value: 65, 66) -> 50, 10, 5, byte-separator, 50, 10, 5, 1`, something like that)

Comment: I'm not sure how much this would help as you still need the endpoints/emoji in the source. Maybe having an emoji font installed isn't too strict of a requirement? If you still want to test would string comparisons work? That way you don't even need to look at any of the outputs, just see if tests pass

Comment: It's recommended that you delete the sandbox post and edit it into a link to the main post after you post it.

Comment: By the way, the sandbox FAQ recommends that people leave posts in the sandbox for at least 72 hours (apparently nobody reads that?)

Answer (score 0):

## Is the Skat null game safe? [WIP] [skat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skat) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

For everyone who knows the card game Skat. Did you ever wondered when playing a null game: is this really safe to win regardless the other player cards? Well, let's try to solve this question with code.

### The Skat game

Skat is card game with 32 cards. There are four colours: Diamonds ♦️, Hearts ♥️, Spades ♠️ and Clubs ♣️. Each colour has: Ace, King, Queen, Jack, 10, 9, 8 and 7. Three players are playing, so each one get 10 cards. The remaining two cards are called Skat and remain covered. Before each game it is to decide which of the three players plays alone against the other two which play together. The alone player gets the possibility to exchange one or two of his cards against one or two of the covered cards in the Skat. More about Skat can be read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat_(card_game)).

### The null game

There are times when get so bad cards, i.e. no Aces and no Jacks, that they will indeed really good, namely when you can't make any points, not even a trick with the cards.

### The task

Write a program that will determine if an input of ten cards of the 32 cards will guarantee that the player will win the null game, i.e. the player won't get any tricks regardless how the other 22 cards are distributed for the other two players and whether or not the alone player is in forehand. You can assume any reasonable input and output that suits you. For convenience a reasonably sorting of the cards can also be assumed.

One note to the forehand rule: it is assumed that the alone player wants to win so he or she won't sabotage the game with drawing an Ace or similar high cards.

### Test cases

Let's assume an array of two character strings where the first represents the colour (D for Diamond, etc.) and the second the value (7, 8, 9, X, J, Q, K, A) E.g `['D7','D8','D9','H7','H8','C7','C8','CX','CQ','CA']` will result in `true` indicating that this null game cannot be lost.

[more to come]

This is code-golf so the shortest code wins.

Comment: (you didn't specify what's the condition for winning in the game...)

Comment: I enjoy playing Skat, so this challenge looks promising even though it still misses some important parts in order to be accessible for people who have never heard about Skat. For the sake of simplicity (as the challenge already looks rather hard) I'd suggest to drop the forehand part (and assume one of the opponents plays first). Otherwise it needs to be specified which cards are allowed to be played.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will try to find some time for improving this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Colorize a diff, unified format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218755/96279)

Comment: Print to stdout? What about displaying it on the screen or write an image? (you know there are standard output formats...

Comment: @user202729 They will print to stdout with ANSI escape sequences, I have edited my question.

Comment: (just noticed that you're a new user. Anyway) people generally don't like restrictive input/output format. (https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) And the command-line parsing appears to be unrelated to the challenge (except making it "looks like a typical Unix tools")

Comment: @user202729 I agree, I changed it so it doesn't have the restriction anymore

Comment: you may want to ban usage of git tools from shell for this challenge.

Comment: @Razetime "Do X without Y" (including banning built-ins) is not recommended. Boring answers will usually be downvoted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## Which Ninjutsu am I casting? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218805/which-ninjutsu-am-i-casting)

Comment: Bad title considering that validation is the smallest part of the challenge, but it looks pretty good otherwise

Comment: @UnrelatedString I changed the title.

Comment: (note that it's recommended (in the sandbox FAQ) to leave sandbox posts for at least 72 hours.

Answer (score 0):

## Trilobaccis' speed

The challenge is inspired by this beautiful one: [Speed of Lobsters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217690/speed-of-lobsters). And it's similar to this other one: [Is it a lobster number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217960/is-it-a-lobster-number).

The word *Trilobacci* is a blend of *Tribonacci* and *Lobster*.

About tribonacci, quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers):

> The tribonacci numbers are like the Fibonacci numbers, but instead of starting with two predetermined terms, the sequence starts with three predetermined terms and each term afterwards is the sum of the preceding three terms.

Regarding lobsters and speed, they refer to [this subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpeedOfLobsters/) where people have fun editing the text of images to create new phrases.

#### The challenge

The challenge is to "blank out" the digits of given numbers (let's say a,b,c) using the digit of other numbers (say x,y,z) which you have to find by yourself, and then tell whether you could use all the digits from x,y,z to blank out some (or even all) of the digits from a,b,c.

Being more specific: given three positive integers in ascending order, which are necessarily part of a tribonacci sequence (at least the one they can generate), find the three numbers that generated the sequence and use them to blank out the original input numbers according to the lobsters rules.
Then output a truthy value if you used all the digits from the found numbers, or a falsy value if you are left with digits that couldn't be used to blank out the input digits.

**For the numbers generating the sequence, I mean the the three smallest non-negative integers being part of the sequence.**

#### Lobsters rule!

Start taking the first digit of the first number of x,y,z and blank out its first occurrence in the digits of a,b,c. Then proceed with the next digit from x,y,z looking for its first occurrence in a,b,c, **starting from where you left**.

#### Examples

Given

```
[ 13, 23, 43 ]
```

you'll find out that they are part of a sequence generated by

```
[ 1, 3, 3 ]
```

so then you can proceed at the speed of lobsters:

```
[ 1, 3, 3 ]   --->   [ 13, 23, 43 ]
               ||
              _||_
              \  /
               \/
[ X, 3, 3 ]   --->   [ *3, 23, 43 ]

[ X, X, 3 ]   --->   [ **, 23, 43 ]

[ X, X, X ]   --->   [ **, 2*, 43 ]
```

And in this case you output a **truthy** value because you used all the digits from `[ 1, 3, 3 ]`.

The numbers `[ 903, 1661, 3055 ]` are also generated by `[ 1, 3, 3 ]`, but the output for them is a **falsy** value:

```
[ 1, 3, 3 ]   --->   [ 903, 1661, 3055 ]
               ||
              _||_
              \  /
               \/
[ X, 3, 3 ]   --->   [ 903, *661, 3055 ]

[ X, X, 3 ]   --->   [ 903, *661, *055 ]

[ X, X, 3 ]   --->   [ 903, *661, *055 ] can't find any 3 after the last blanked digit
```

#### Input

Three integers. (One by one, into an array, as one or more a strings, split like bananas, etc.)
You can even take them in descending order if like.

#### Output

Choose a truthy and a falsy value and be consistent with them.

[Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, with [standard I/O conventions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), while [default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

It would be nice if you could provide an easy way to try your program and possibly an explanation of how it works.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest wins.

#### Test cases

Soon...

## Meta

- Any feedback / suggestion?
- I thought about considering the digits of x,y,z as always, but blanking out their occurrence in a,b,c from right-to-left, so that who participated to the previous lobster challenges would have to renew this part of the answer. Do you think it would be a good thing?

Comment: Nice challenge, maybe a bit convoluted but I like it. I'd mention somewhere that the numbers in a tribonacci sequence need to all be positive, otherwise for example [1,3,3] could come after [-1,1,3] and there would be no beginning. I believe going left-to-right or right-to-left in the last step does not make any difference, if one of them is possible the other one will be as well

Comment: @Leo I am going to highlight *"For the numbers generating the sequence, I mean the the three smallest non-negative integers being part of the sequence."* And I'll specify that the input is positive. Regarding the right-to-left, thing, I expressed it so badly: I meant considering the digits of x,y,z LtR as always, but blanking their occurrence in a,b,c in RtL direction. Since you are already finding the sequence in reverse, it could make sense to rename the challenge like *Retrolobacci* and do the LtR thing, but I don't know.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had missed the part about non-negative integers! To make it completely dumb-proof (read: Leo-proof) you could add a "positive" also to the input description section. Also, some people will probably want to take the input numbers backwards, I don't know if this is already a default but it may be worth explicitly allowing it in the text. I think Trilobacci sounds better than Retrolobacci, but other than that I have no opinion on LtR vs RtL :)

Comment: @Leo I added the backward input, thank you! I don't like Retrolobacci either, it could be *"Trilobaccis' speed, when running backwards"*, maybe too long but somehow funny.

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge

Print all the [Tamil characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) in any order you like. They should be 12 vowels, 18 consonants and the special symbol ஃ .

Your code should not print anything except for those letters but it can print one letter per line.

The consonants are: க் ங் ச் ஞ் ட் ண் த் ந் ப் ம் ய் ர் ல் வ் ழ் ள் ற் ன்

The vowels are: அ ஆ இ ஈ உ ஊ எ ஏ ஐ ஒ ஓ ஔ

Shortest code wins

Comment: @user Done.  I hope it helps.

Comment: There isn't really a point in doing this: 31 bytes, copy-paste the letters.

Comment: @fasterthanlight if you add the print statement do you think you won’t be able to do any better? Also, how would you do it in C for example?

Comment: I don't specialize in C. For example, in O5AB1E, you can just do `,"க் ங் ச் ஞ் ட் ண் த் ந் ப் ம் ய் ர் ல் வ் ழ் ள் ற் ன் அ ஆ இ ஈ உ ஊ எ ஏ ஐ ஒ ஓ ஔ ஃ` in 33 bytes, excluding spaces

Comment: @fasterthanlight and no more compact way to go over the relevant Unicode characters?

Comment: @fasterthanlight what about if I changed it to printing all the Unicode Tamil symbols?

Comment: Could you also include the Unicode codepoints of the characters? I think that would make it easier for solvers to consider strategies for generating them.

Comment: @xnor yes I will do that. Do you think 31 characters is too few for it to be interesting?

Comment: @Anush I think it depends how the code points are distributed, whether they're not too random or too ordered.

Answer (score 0):

## Generate a "Pi-ey" number

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Generate the smallest integer of the form \$x^x\$ with \$10^{n-1}\cdotπ\$ digits, rounded down, given \$n\$. If there is no such number, take the nearest number that has as many digits of \$π\$ in its digit count. For example, if \$n=5\$, then the number of digits would be 31415. If there was no such number of form \$x^x\$, then take the nearest digit count similar to 31415, like 31414 and 31416.

If there are multiple values of \$x\$ that will work, whichever one is closer to \$3.1415926e3141...\$ will be the chosen value. For instance, if two solutions for \$n=5\$ were \$1.234e31414\$ and \$1.234e31416\$, we would select the former, as it is closer to \$3.1415926...e31415\$.

Test cases:

[image: Glitchy picture]

### Rules:

- Shortest amount of bytes of code wins
- Please post the number of bytes as well as the runtime for \$n=5\$.
- It is recommended that you post your score (below), but is not required.

### Scoring

- Your score will be based on your program time and length. \$\text{score} = \text{program length in bytes} + 10 \times \text{time to execute in seconds}\$

Comment: The first paragraph seems unclear to me. For the \$n\pi\$ digits, do we round that down, or to the nearest integer? The second sentence seems a little unclear as well, do you mean to find the number that's closest to having \$n\pi\$ digits? If so, if there are multiple (let's say \$1.1234e313\$ and \$1.1234e315\$), which one should be chosen?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms For the \$n\pi\$ digits, round down. For you second question, if \$n=5\$, you would find the closest number of form \$x^x\$ with 31415 digits. If there is no such number, with 31415 digits, then find the nearest number with a digit count closest to 31415 (i.e. 31414, 31416, etc). To answer your last question, the number that is closer to \$3.141926535...e314\$ will be selected if there are multiple.

Comment: I'd recommend editing that into the post, when you include that information it's much more clear. Also, you might want to put the test cases in as text rather than an image to make them easier to copy-paste. Other than that, it looks clear to me, but I'd wait a day or two to make sure nothing else is unclear. (Don't worry, it's way better than my first post :p)

Comment: Program length plus time in what? Seconds? On what machine? Combining length and speed in this way is very sensitive to how the speed is measured. Taking a step back, getting this tradeoff to be balanced and interesting for golfers is very hard, possibly impossible across a wide range of languages of varying golfiness and speed. I'd strongly recommend against this, especially for your first challenge. I think either [tag:code-golf] or [tag:fastest-code] would be better.

Comment: @xnor I have changed my post so that it will be easier, with point bonuses as needed

Comment: @fasterthanlight [Bonuses have fallen really out of favor with the community](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/20260). Including this many large bonuses is virtually guaranteed to get your challenge downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for moving your post to the sandbox. I generally agree with xnor that trying to score in this way is ill-advised, but if you want to continue with it you should decide for which values you will test the speed. In addition, assuming I am understanding correctly, the output is the full value \$ x^{x} \$. I think it is possible that an efficient answer will spend more time printing out this number than it would take to calculate it, which seems to somewhat defeat the purpose.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman So how can you tell when a program is done calculating something?

Comment: Ah, sorry I meant to suggest that just asking for \$ x \$ should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219158/verify-the-inequality)

Comment: The issue with the requirement is that it's non-observable. While it's true that sometimes we judge answers by *understanding* it (especially when answerers have to prove something about the answers), most people consider it problematic.

Comment: Language having no random function a problem, we have rules for that.

Comment: Meta post about non-observable requirement: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/should-we-disallow-non-observable-requirements

Comment: You could make it observable by requiring that the results of intermediate steps be output.

Comment: even in this case people can still always output the sum... (although it will probably not save that much) (besides you can remove the "rules" part)

Comment: Remark: by default "random" means "all values are possible in theory". https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17563/are-non-uniform-random-distributions-allowed [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you properly @user202729, but the elements in `a` *do* cover all values possible in theory, as long as their sum is 1.

Comment: Yes, generally it's not a problem.

Comment: As I 've said above , people might skip the final compare solution, although I see no way to enforce it. Otherwise clear enough [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: I think your "print" in step 3 and "return" in step 5 is to say that both these results should be output, but it should allow both to be printed or returned in a pair. I'd suggested rewording to say that these two things need to be "output", which is generic enough to cover both functions and programs. The short-circuiting in step 1 of outputting a negative number is not ideal because it's [Requiring multiple types as return value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17048/20260). I'd suggest thinking if there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: It's not clear to me in step 2 what is required for a random array of non-negative reals summing to 1. Must it be uniform on that `(n-1)`-dimensional space? See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/20260). I think you should say explicitly what is expected -- the meta post that user202729 linked to isn't really definitive.

Comment: Fixed @xnor, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes about the randomness, but see my other comment.

Comment: @xnor What about changing the negative number in step 1 into throwing an error / exception? For step 3 & 5, what about saying "output" these two results?

Comment: @SketchySketch Throwing an error/exception might also be too language specific. Maybe just allow any behavior that's not output of the form in the later steps? Though, is this complication of checking `n>=4` even worth having in the challenge? Its seems like a straightforward extra bit to add in. You could just have the input guarantee that `n>=4`.

Comment: Yes, what you have said for "output" looks good. I think you can remove the parts about what types of things the code can be and the output form, since [we already have defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and listing all of them would be prohibitive. By the way, consensus is against allowing snippets.

Comment: @xnor It's not throwing an error now; changed it to 'terminate the program'.

Comment: "Terminate the program" is still making [assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/20260) and implies the code is a program rather than a function. And it's arguably [unobservable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20260) whether the program terminates here or if it continues but declines to output at a later step, which I think should be an option.

Comment: already fixed @xnor I wrote that "you may assume n >= 4", and deleted step 1.

Answer (score 0):

[post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219203/100303)

Comment: The main issue with fastest-code is that you need to specify the specification of a machine to judge solutions on, and a set of test cases. (note that 8x8x8 is probably too small for meaningful timing) (There's also [tag:golf-CPU] and [tag:atomic-code-golf], but I don't see the former used much) [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the comments. Already updated.

Comment: I can't tell if N=16 is sufficient (the input data size is N^3, the time complexity is probably O(N^3 log(N)) -- or O(N^6)? I don't know), but because of the fluctuation in runtime because of various reasons, make sure that the run time of the fastest solution on the largest test case is at least a few seconds so it can be reliably measured.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the mentioned point about the fluctuation in runtime. I choose N = 16, 25 and 30 for measuring. If there is any other issue of this challenge, please let me know.

Comment: there might be several languages with built in for this. // 
 there might be n^3 log n solutions which will be very fast anyway, but (I think) it's okay to fix the test cases later (I assume you're solving it in n^6?) -- but in this case whether the challenge is interesting is another matter.  // Otherwise looks good. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the analysis spectrum

This is based on a task I had in work a few years back.

A [diode-array detector](https://www.chromatographyonline.com/view/how-does-it-work-part-iv-ultraviolet-detectors) (DAD) is a kind of chromatography detector which fires light into a sample and detects the strength of the light that passes through it at different wavelengths. From this you can determine, among other things, the contents or the purity of the sample.

Most detectors can only detect on one wavelength. A DAD however can scan across a spectrum of wavelengths, typically from 190nm to 650nm. From that spectrum we can then pick out the wavelengths that we're interested in. Maybe for our sample we want to analyse it at wavelengths 300nm, 350nm, and 550nm. These are called 'channels'.

Each wavelength may also have a bandwidth across which the signal strength is averaged. If we have analyse on wavelength 420nm, with a bandwidth of 10nm, the range for that channel would be from 415nm to 425nm (5nm lower, 5nm higher than the base wavelength). However, this bandwidth is optional.

The DAD we'll be working with does not take a set of channels, but rather we must provide it with a minimum wavelength and a maximum wavelength to detect across. This will be our task.

### The Challenge

Write a program or function that, when given a collection of channels, determines the lowest and highest wavelength to analyse across for these channels.

For this challenge, a channel consists of an integer wavelength, and an optional integer bandwidth. The wavelength can be positive or negative, but the bandwidth is always positive.

Bandwidths can be odd numbers, but in that case you would then shrink it down to an even number.

The upper limit can be the same as the lower limit, but can never be smaller.

Also, you can safely assume that at least one channel is given to your code.

### Example 1

```
Channel 1
Wavelength = 420
Bandwidth = 10
```

For channel 1, the base wavelength is 420 and the bandwidth is 10.

Channel 1's lower range is the base wavelength minus half of the bandwidth. In this case, it's `420 - (10 / 2) = 415`. The upper range is the base wavelength plus half of the bandwidth: `420 + (10 / 2) = 425`.

Answers: `Lower = 415, upper = 425`

### Example 2

```
Channel 1
Wavelength = 394
Bandwidth = 19

Channel 2
Wavelength = 500
Bandwidth = N/A
```

For channel 1, the base wavelength is 394 and the bandwidth is 19. Because the bandwidth is an odd number, and our DAD cannot accept floating-point numbers, we can round it down to 18.

Channel 1's lower range is the base wavelength minus half of the bandwidth. In this case, it's `394 - (18 / 2) = 385`. The upper range is the base wavelength plus half of the bandwidth: `394 + (18 / 2) = 403`.

Channel 2 has no bandwidth, so it's range is just at its base wavelength: 500.

Comparing the channel ranges, channel 1 has the minimum lower limit with 385. Channel 2 has the maximum upper limit, with 500.

Answers: `Lower = 385, upper = 500`

### Test cases

```
Test case 1:

Wavelength 1 = 400
Bandwidth 1 = N/A

Answers: lower = 400, upper = 400

-------------------------------------

Test case 2:

Wavelength 1 = 200
Bandwidth 1 = 15

Answers: lower = 193, upper = 207

-------------------------------------

Test case 3:

Wavelength 1 = 394
Bandwidth 1 = 19

Wavelength 2 = 500
Bandwidth 2 = N/A

Answers: lower = 385, upper = 500

-------------------------------------

Test case 4:

Wavelength 1 = 394
Bandwidth 1 = 40

Wavelength 2 = 500
Bandwidth 2 = 10

Wavelength 3 = 380
Bandwidth 3 = 5

Answers: lower = 374, upper = 505
```

### Rules

The range that you must produce must consist of an integer lower limit and an integer upper limit. This particular DAD cannot accept decimal numbers, so while your code may accept and output floating-point types, *the values themselves must be whole numbers.*

Computing this range is important for other settings on the DAD. Therefore, you may not take just any input and return an extremely small lower limit and/or an extremely large upper limit. Your outputs *must* be based on your inputs.

[Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422), including [the default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/). Similarly, [default loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

Finally, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Sandbox Questions

- Is the challenge itself too complex or too easy?
- Is the requirement for whole-numbered outputs valid, or does it seem a little bit arbitrary?
- Are the examples and the test cases useful?
- Finally, would this be an interesting challenge?

Comment: Some notes: (1) is it guaranteed that the outputted "lower value" will always be strictly greater than zero? (2) It appears that most people will want to take N/A bandwidth as zero. (3) of course requiring floor/ceil is "valid", whether it's arbitrary is up to people. (4) while I can understand the challenge, it's mainly because I read the provided example explanation, so I can't be entirely sure that the rules part is clear enough. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Answer (score 0):

## Print the nth sequence from oeis

The input is one natural number n - the sequence number

Your task is to put this numeric link https://oeis.org/A (example of a link with n = 1: https://oeis.org/A1), then you should get the html of this page and get the sequence from there

Examples:

```
n -> sequence
1 -> 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 15, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 51, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 2, 2, 14, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 52, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 15, 2, 13, 2, 2, 1, 13, 1, 2, 4, 267, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 52, 15, 2, 1, 15, 1, 2, 1, 12, 1, 10, 1, 4, 2
2 -> 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2
3 -> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 8, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 8, 4, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8, 4, 4, 8, 8, 3, 8, 8, 4, 7, 4, 4, 10, 6, 6, 8, 4, 5, 8, 6, 4, 9, 8, 4, 10, 6, 4, 12, 8, 6, 6, 4, 8, 8, 8, 4, 8, 6, 4
4 -> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
5 -> 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 2, 8, 2, 6, 6, 4, 2, 10, 3, 6, 4, 6, 2, 8, 4, 8, 4, 4, 2, 12, 2, 4, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, 8, 2, 12, 2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 8, 2, 10, 5, 4, 2, 12, 4, 4, 4, 8, 2, 12, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 12, 2, 6, 6, 9, 2, 8, 2, 8
6 -> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18
7 -> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
8 -> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 40, 43, 49, 52, 58, 64, 70, 76, 82, 88, 98, 104, 114, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 195, 205, 220, 230, 245, 260, 275, 290, 305, 320, 341, 356, 377, 392, 413, 434, 455, 476, 497, 518, 546
9 -> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142, 165, 192, 222, 256, 296, 340, 390, 448, 512, 585, 668, 760, 864, 982, 1113, 1260, 1426, 1610, 1816, 2048, 2304, 2590, 2910, 3264, 3658, 4097, 4582, 5120, 5718, 6378
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [code golf - Automate the OEIS - Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89376/automate-the-oeis) except that this one requires printing all values. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

### Book cipher

A [Book cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_cipher) is a very unique method of a [encipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher). Here's how's it done:

- You have a book / a document or a article (something full of text, the more pages of text the better).
- You have a message to convey (a secret, of some sort)
- You simply-put read trough the text and the secret message *(may come from input, or reading it from 2 separate files)* - split it into words *(so, separate spaces, commas and [dots])* **so,  ',' , '.' and spaces is the only requirement, how is not really that hugely important** and you keep the count of how many words there are in the text, now input the **secret message *(note, the secret's words must be in the text, so if you secret was "My Secret" then, the words "My" and "Secrets" must both exist in the text.***) and output the position of the inputted **secret message**. (E.g if the word "My" was nearly at the first page, maybe the 20th Word in the text, the program should print out '20'. Same with the word "Secrets", if that maybe were later, (let say the 93th word in the text) then your program should print out '93'.

**Note the data type of input and output:**

output numbers: Integers.

Input numbers: Integers

( **Excluding if the secret actually contains a number, then it does not need to be treated as a int. Can be a plus if it does but is not necessary.**)

#### Mini Example:

document.txt - file that contains text.

Secret: "My Secret"

(in the text, this is the 20th and the 93th word) (Note, this is only a made up secret, it is not from a real file, or a real input) a more better example is below.

### Program input:

You enter "My Secret"

### Program output:

> 20

> 93

`And, again - you enter those numbers(**Integers**):`

> 20 93

### Program outputs:

> My

> Secret

*this is just to show how input and outputs are related to each other.*

For reference (if needed) You have a Python3 implementation available at my GitHub page, to see a book cipher in action
here: [GitHub - Book cipher in Py3](https://github.com/loneicewolf/Book-Cipher-Python)

- Why is this challenge interesting?

I personally think this is a educational (and interesting) challenge ( one might also exercise, because of how simple it might seem to make, but really took myself - literally **years** to even **know** **how** **to** **implement** this correctly)

Interesting article to get some background of what Cicada3301 is (**not my site**) - https://www.clevcode.org/cicada-3301/

[Wikipedia: Cicada3301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicada_3301)

I created this challenge both to, see other peoples methods of solving this (you are free to use any programming language!) and also - how long it would take others (For me, really I think it took more than 4 years actually - even in Python3. It looks simple but, for me - *really not*)

- A motivating fact: There are **still** so little info (especially on example codes) on the internet(at least by the time writing this challenge)  about just, book cipher ***implementations***

## Challenge

I would highly suggest making dedicated functions for this challenge

- (instead of writing all code in the main() function - but it's totally fine to have it all in main!)

#### Operation:

Here's how the program should read, process, and output the result:

First, take the text (the book/document, with the lots of text, (**not the secret**))
and:

**Note: The text can either be entered or read from a file. You choose this.**

1. read it (From a file, or enter it as input)
2. split it into words (by, I.e detecting '.', spaces(' '), and commas ',')
   (Or if you already have split the input & are ready to move on to step 3, do that :) )
3. count the number of words.

Repeat this process with the Secret input part.

So, the input secret part should be:

- read it (from, again a file or enter it as input)
- split it (i.e if your input was "My Secret" - split it into words like so: "My" "Secret")

#### My Python3 implementation only separate spaces.

The Key sequence - this is the n*th* words  your text contains, e.g the 93th word in above example "Secrets".

#### The winner will be chosen by how short the code is. (So, the shortest code = **win**)

## Example Input and Output

`example file used 'document1.txt'in this section is available at the GitHub page.` 
`as well as the Python3 file used in the example below.`

`The output of your program should match the output of the Python3 program.`

## Input:

`python3 bookcipher.py`

> input text: a house with a Bob inside

## Output:

> you entered these words:
> ['a', 'house', 'with', 'a', 'Bob', 'inside']

> 2

> 3

> 5

> 2

> 0

> 30

## Input again: (decrypting)

> input key-sequence sep. With spaces: 2 3 5 2 0 30

> a

> house

> with

> a

> Bob

> inside

Comment: I am new, this is the first challenge, but feel free to edit/ask for clarification/ anything! Thanks, I hope the guys at the orig. Post led me to the right place; if this is not the correct place(or way!) to add proposal; please tell me how I would go around of doing that!  //Have a **Corona Free** week!

Comment: You're in the right place. Well done!

Comment: @Adam  thanks; I am still a bit new here, but should I wait now - or what specifically should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, this is a pretty good challenge! I would suggest being a bit more liberal with the input format (allowing solutions to read from STDIN or take the "book" as a function argument instead of reading from a file). I would also suggest splitting this up into two challenges - encrypting and decrypting - but that's up to you. As for what you should do now - just wait a few days so you can get feedback and modify your question, and then you can post on the main site.

Comment: If your proposal goes unnoticed for a really long time, you might also want to ask others to review it in the site's [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: I generally recommend leaving challenges here for minimum a week as people ave various schedules, e.g. only visiting on weekends or only on (certain) weekdays.

Comment: Just to make sure... did you address all the problems raised in the comments under the main site post?

Comment: @user202729 Oh,  maybe not -  fixed now though, thanks for pointing it out, and okay with the chat - got it :)

Comment: (note that I'm not the same user as [user]. Even the chat highlight is wrong)

Comment: The text could be more concise and flow more logically. Right now I see five sections: (1) description of the cipher, (2) example (3) personal background, (4) requirements for the code, (5) more examples. I think you should aim to merge (1) and (4) where possible (there's some redundancy there), and likewise (2) and (5). (3) is not really relevant and should (I think) be deleted.

Comment: I also suggest formatting the examples using code blocks instead of block quotes.

Answer (score 0):

## Subbasis. Generate. Discrete?

### Objective

Given finitely many finite sets, interpret them as a subbasis to generate a space, and decide whether the resulting topology is discrete.

### Introduction to Topology

Given a set \$X\$, a **topology** \$\mathcal{T}\$ over \$X\$ is a subset of the power set \$\mathcal{P}(X)\$ such that:

- \$\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{T}\$.
- For all \$\space \mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{T}\$, \$\bigcup\mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{T}\$.
- For all \$Y_1, Y_2 \in \mathcal{T}\$, \$Y_1 \cap Y_2 \in \mathcal{T}\$.

Members of a topology are said to be **open**. So the rules above in plaintext are:

- The empty set and \$X\$ itself are open.
- The union of arbitrarily many open sets is open.
- The intersection of finitely many open sets is open.

Endowed with a topology, \$X\$ is said to be a (topological) **space**.

If \$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{P}(X)\$, \$\mathcal{T}\$ is said to be **discrete**.

### Basis and Subbasis

A subset \$\mathcal{B}\$ of the power set \$\mathcal{P}(X)\$ is said to be a **basis** (pl. **bases**) of a set \$X\$ if:

- For all \$x \in X\$, there exists \$B \in \mathcal{B}\$ such that \$x \in B\$.
- For all \$B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}\$, there exists \$C \in \mathcal{B}\$ such that \$C \subset B_1 \cap B_2\$.

We take every subset \$\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{B}\$ and declare \$\bigcup\mathcal{U}\$ to be open to **generate** a topology \$\mathcal{T}\$. Note that \$\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{T}\$ always holds.

If we omit the second requirement, we have a **subbasis** of \$X\$. A subbasis generates a topology by also declaring the intersection of *finitely* many members to be open.

### Input and Output

Given a set of finitely many finite sets \$\mathcal{S}\$, \$X\$ shall be implicitly defined as \$\bigcup\mathcal{S}\$. Note that by this, the first requirement for bases always holds.

The input/output format is flexible. In every case, inputs that don't fit in your input format fall in *don't care* situation.

### Examples

#### Truthy

- \$\emptyset\$ (Generates \$X = \emptyset\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset\}\$)
- \$\{\emptyset\}\$ (Ditto)
- \$\{\{0\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{0\}\}\$)
- \$\{\emptyset,\{0\}\}\$ (Ditto)
- \$\{\{1\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{1\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0\},\{1\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\$ (Ditto)
- \$\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1,2\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\}\$ (Ditto)

#### Falsy

- \$\{\{0,1\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0,1\},\{1\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0\},\{1,2\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1,2\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}\$)
- \$\{\{0,1\},\{1\},\{2\}\}\$ (Generates \$X = \{0,1,2\}\$ and \$\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}\$)

Comment: This looks math-heavy. To get a better chance of having it reviewed (because people, including me, tend to skip long sandbox posts) you can ask in chat and leave it in for a while.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, defining `U(S)` as the union of all members of `S` and `P(S)` as the powerset of `S`, you are asking whether `{U(x) for x in P(X)} == P(U(X))`?
In this case a more to the point description like this one could be useful... You can leave the math background in (maybe shorten it a little bit) for people interested, but it shouldn't be the only description for the challenge.

Comment: @Leo Figuring out a simple algorithm to solve the challenge can be part of it. (although after the first answer is posted people can just use the same algorithm, however nobody is forced to look at the answers; besides the "original" answer tend to be upvoted proportionally anyway)

Comment: @Leo (your notation is confusing because you use `X` for the input while OP uses it for `U(input)`, but it looks correct) [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 I agree that figuring out the algorithm is part of the challenge, but having to understand several paragraph of relatively advanced math concepts is a bit detrimental to the challenge itself, in my opinion. Moreover, mine is not necessarily the best algorithm, just a simpler description of the requirements. You are right about the different notation, sorry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

## Decode an 8086 MOD R/M

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[bitwise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitwise)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

I think this *might* be fun. Or, it might be torture, idk.  If this is popular, I might add a sequel for the significantly more complex 32-bit encoding

Time for a mini objdump.

An 8086 MOD R/M field is laid out like so:

```
MOD  REG  R/M |  OPTIONAL DISPLACEMENTS
mm   rrr  rrm | (iiiiiiii) | (iiiiiiii)
76   543  210 |  76543210  |  76543210
```

REG is a register. Quite unintuitively, the register names are not in alphabetical order.

Note that you can safely assume a word register, not a half byte register, and that the destination is a register.

```
REG |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
Name| AX | CX | DX | BX | SP | BP | SI | DI |
```

MOD determines the length and format of the instruction.

```
MOD | FORMAT
 0  | [MEM] or [ADDR]
 1  | [MEM+/-disp8] (signed 8-bit immediate)
 2  | [MEM+/-disp16] (signed 16-bit little endian immediate)
 3  | REG
```

MEM is parsed as so:

```
MEM  |    0    |    1    |    2    |    3    |   4  |   5  |   6   |   7  |
Name | [BX+SI] | [BX+DI] | [BP+SI] | [BP+DI] | [SI] | [DI] | [BP]* | [BX] |
*when MOD==0, [BP] is replaced by an absolute 16-bit address.

Just [BP] is encoded as [BP+0].
```

I am going to [represent MOD R/M as octal](https://gist.github.com/seanjensengrey/f971c20d05d4d0efc0781f2f3c0353da), and addresses/displacements as hex. It really bugs me how few people write it this way, as it makes much more sense.

So, for example:

```
MOD  r  r/m
 3   0    0
reg  |    |
    AX,  AX

 0   2    0
mem  |    |
    DX,[BX+SI]

 1   3   7 , 23
M+D8 |   |   |
    BX, [BX+0x23]

 2   2   1 , BC 6A
M+D16|   |    | /
    DX,[BX+DI+0x6ABC]
```

Rules:

- You may take your input as a packed integer, byte array, string in any mix of bases, or whatever. I'm not picky. I personally wrote them as mixed hex and octal.
- You will always get 3 bytes, **however**, in true objdump spirit, **those extra bytes will be random**. The first byte is all you need to determine the length.
- Not all cases will be the most efficient encoding.
- In the output:

  - It may be returned as a single string, or printed.
  - It is case insensitive
  - It can have excess spaces or tabs, but it must be on one line.
  - It can have an optional trailing newline
  - Displacements and addresses can be in any base, however, do note that displacements are signed two's complement and will be subtracted if negative. So, for `100 FF`, `AX,[BX+SI+0xFF]` is wrong.
  - Leading zeroes and displacements of zero are fine.

Test cases (irrelevant bytes are in italics):

```
300 73 A2 -> AX,AX
312 01 82 -> CX,DX
337 3E 1C -> BX,DI
020 24 AF -> DX,[BX+SI]
137 23 6B -> BX,[BX+0x23]
066 34 21 -> SI,[0x1234]
166 00 10 -> SI,[BP+0x00]
221 BC 6A -> DX,[BX+DI+0x6ABC]
124 FF EF -> CX,[SI-0x01]
224 FF FF -> CX,[SI-0x0001]
240 00 00 -> SP,[BX+SI+0x0000]
```

Comment: How is "300" 3 bytes? It looks like 3 octal digits.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: What is `R/M`? Why is `MEM` 3 bits long?

Comment: Since you list out the bytes as bits (appropriately), it would probably be clearer if you also included the binary values in the tables for reg/mod/mem. Using the octal/hex format is probably also going to confuse people - I think labeling your examples with what base is being used may help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Posted [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219693/upper-case-%d1%81l%d0%besed)

Comment: The test cases are rather confusing. Are they missing the expected output? In addition, your statement about "dots" is rather odd - do you mean all non-letter characters should be ignored, or just punctuation, or just periods? You should definitely also specify what characters can appear in the input.

Comment: I think I get it, but it needs to be explained better.  For each value of `n` less than the length of the word, the letters that are `n` slots from the beginning and `n` slots from the end of the word should both be made uppercase if either of them is upper case.

Comment: Perhaps replacing "slot" by "position"/"character" is easier (perhaps it's a perl term? I don't know), but otherwise clear enough. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Answer (score 0):

## Create a QR quine

(a "qruine" if you will)

Design a QR code that legibly spells with its pixels (or the space between them) the text that it scans to.

For example, this QR code scans to the letter A, and also spells out A in white:

[image]

It does not matter what the scanned and displayed text is; it does not have to be coherent or readable.

The winner is the person with the longest text.

Comment: This is a really cool idea, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. (*pulls out qr code scanner*) Oh, never mind, it really does just scan as 'A'. This surprises me for how big it is.

Comment: Does this count as code-golf?

Answer (score 0):

## Is this code in the same language as my answer? (WIP)

Probably a bad idea, but the goal here is to output a truthy value if a given input string is valid syntax in the same language as your answer.

Comment: Maybe use neural networks and allow answers to have approx. 80% accuracy? I personally don't think this is all that interesting (and it would be very hard to score), but that's completely subjective.

Comment: Terrible question in most languages. Either they use `compile` (eval might loop infinitely)  or they just print a truthy value (in esoteric languages where all programs are valid)

Comment: nop in languages with no syntax

Answer (score 0):

## I don't care how it started, but I'm going to end it!

[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

---

Given a number between 0 and 10,000 (inclusive) as input, output that many arbitrary* printable ASCII characters, followed by the exact text:

```
I don't care how it started, but I'm going to end it!
```

<sub>* The arbitrary preceding text must not contain the ending text.</sub>

You do not need to verify the input value.

Comment: Nothing to review. (people will print sequence of `a` most likely)

Answer (score 0):

## Shortest and Asymptotically Fastest Sort of 3-Tuples

Tags: [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Write the shortest and asymptotically fastest function or program that will sort a set of 3-tuples.

## Input

Input is a set (or unique list, array, etc) of 3-tuples, containing positive integers.

## Output

Output is a set (or unique list, array, etc) of 3-tuples sorted in the following way:

- The first elements of each tuple are monotonically increasing.
- For each value of the first elements, the second elements are monotonically increasing.
- For each value of the second elements, the third elements are monotonically increasing.

## Additional Rules

- As well as a byte count, include the asymptotic time complexity spent by your program.
- Explanations are encouraged! (Especially for showing the time complexity)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Input and output is flexible, as long as each 3-tuple is individually identifiable.
- Scoring is time complexity, with byte length as a tie breaker.

## Examples

```
Input - Output # Comment
[(1,2,3), (400,500,600), (0,0,0)] - [(0,0,0), (1,2,3), (400,500,600)]
[(1,0,255), (1,255,0), (1,10,123), (1,50,96)]
 - [(1,0,255), (1,10,123), (1,50,96), (1,255,0)] # sorted by second elements
[(1,0,255), (1,0,0), (1,0,123), (1,0,96)]
 - [(1,0,0), (1,0,96), (1,0,123), (1,0,255)] # sorted by third elements
[(1,0,255), (1,255,0), (1,10,123), (1,50,96), (2,0,255), (2,0,0), (2,0,123), (2,0,96)]
 - [(1,0,255), (1,10,123), (1,50,96), (1,255,0), (2,0,0), (2,0,96), (2,0,123), (2,0,255)] # sorting by first and second
[(1,0,255), (1,255,0), (255,23,232), (1,10,123), (1,50,96), (2,0,255), (2,0,0), (2,0,123), (2,0,96), (1,2,3), (400,500,600), (0,0,0)]
 - [(0,0,0), (1,0,255), (1,2,3), (1,10,123), (1,50,96), (1,255,0), (2,0,0), (2,0,96), (2,0,123), (2,0,255), (400,500,600), (255,23,232)]
```

Comment: Which scoring criterion would take priority? Or is there some way in which they are combined?

Comment: @UnrelatedString I'll add that in, lower time complexity is better.

Comment: Because the input is bounded, all solutions will take O(1).

Comment: The scoring as written is ill-defined. Better saying "asymptotic time complexity is the winning criteria, the size is the tie-breaker" [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: Otherwise, algorithms for sorting things are **very** well-studied already. Fastest-algorithm is not interesting.

Comment: Okay. The other comment (about well-studied) still applies.

Answer (score 0):

## [First sequence with no square differences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220159/first-sequence-with-no-square-differences)

Comment: Clear enough. (I can't find any with the OEIS name. Probably safe.)

Comment: By the way, it's recommended that challenges should be left for at least 72 hours before posting it on the main site (from the sandbox FAQ)

Comment: @user202729 I'm aware, but I used my judgement that the challenge is simple enough that it shouldn't need the full 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

## [Three, Three, No](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220231/three-three-no)

Comment: Some test cases (with example outputs) would be nice. Also, it is discouraged to include input verification in a code golf challenge.

Comment: Do you want to allow programs to take input in unary?

Comment: @Bubbler Actually I think that the input verification is a part of the challenge in this case. Because of the asymptotic time complexity requirement, you need some case-working in the algorithm anyway.

Comment: @user202729 It does require some casework, but if the existence of an answer is guaranteed, you can still cut an entire if-branch (a test and a code to report failure, the latter of which is superfluous and closer to a boilerplate than a core task IMO).

Comment: @Bubbler Depends on what you consider to be valid input. The challenge is just "Given a sequence, print whether there exists a partition and the partition itself if there exists"

Comment: @Bubbler And op doesn't require some long error message to be printed, right? This is closer to the "general falsy value".

Comment: @Bubbler So I should change it to assume that all inputs have a permutation that works?

Comment: @Bubbler I've added some test cases.

Comment: @user101295 *So I should change it to assume that all inputs have a permutation that works?* -- You don't need to strictly follow it. You'll need to include a few more test cases for the "impossible" situation though.

Comment: @Bubbler Updated.

Answer (score 0):

## Lists of power

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Generate the following list of lists.

```
[[0], [1], [2, 4, 8, 6], [3, 9, 7, 1], [4, 6], [5], [6], [7, 9, 3, 1], [8, 4, 2, 6], [9, 1]]
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (as measured in bytes) wins.

Comment: Definitely clear enough. But... (I guess most people would be able to figure out the pattern. It's okay to let answerers to deduce something)

Comment: Should I print the exact string (which [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] implies) or is it fine to write a function that returns an equivalent structure (or print the equivalent structure in the chosen language's way)?

Comment: @Bubbler Ah, I thought [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] just meant it does exactly one thing... The challenge is to write a program or function that creates the structure, not necessarily the string.

Comment: @hakr14 I think you need to include the last sentence in your challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Sequential Multiplication Magic Squares

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

(Inspired by [this question for a 5x5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107606/fill-in-a-5x5-multiplicative-magic-square) and [this question for a 4x4 magic square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107635/fill-in-a-4x4-multiplicative-magic-square) on the Puzzling SE sites.)

For this challenge, a sequential multiplication magic square is an NxN square filled with numbers 1..N² where the product of any M-th row equals the product of the M-th column. That is, the product of the first row is equal to the product of the first column, the product of the second row is equal to the product of the second column etc.

For example, [one such 3x3 square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107606/fill-in-a-5x5-multiplicative-magic-square#comment304271_107606) might be as follows, but other similar results are valid as well:

```
9 8 3
4 5 2
6 1 7
```

Notably, there is no such square for N=2.

### Challenge

Given a side size N of 1 or larger, output a valid NxN sequential multiplication magic square, or any distinct falsy value if none exists.

Standard loopholes apply, any convenient input-output, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Sample cases

```
1 → [1]

2 → any distinct falsy value

3 → [[9, 8, 3],
     [4, 5, 2],
     [6, 1, 7]]

4 → [[16,  3, 12,  4],
     [ 9, 10, 14,  1],
     [ 8,  7, 11, 15],
     [ 2,  6,  5, 13]]

5 → [[ 7, 16,  6,  3, 25],
     [ 5, 13, 22, 12, 24],
     [ 9, 11, 17, 14,  4],
     [20, 18, 21, 19,  1],
     [ 8, 10,  2, 15, 23]]
```

Comment: There's [quite a lot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=magic+square) of questions on magic squares already, I couldn't find one that addresses the above scenario though. I'm not sure whether this is unique enough?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a dupe, but [tag:code-golf] doesn't sound very interesting (mainly because one can generate all possible boards and find one that meets the condition). [tag:fastest-code] would be more interesting, though in that case you'll need to run every single submission on your machine for fair comparison of speed.

Comment: May I error in place of a "distinct falsy value"?

Answer (score 0):

### Syslog PRI Conversion

> This is my first CodeGolf post, so I expect some errors my content.

The `rsyslogd` utility has been a tool used throughout time to handle and parse logs either over an IP network or even locally. As many of you might know, this tool utilizes the basic `syslog` protocol.

The `syslog` protocol handles both a **Facility** and a **Severity** level in one integer, called **Priority**. The formula to extract these levels is as follows:

`Priority = Facility * 8 + Level`

In this challenge, your task is to write an application that converts a **Priority** value from the `syslog` protocol into a human readable format. The application must take input from `STDIN`, and output both the **Severity** and **Facility** string associated with the numerical code.

The numerical code/type table is as follows:

```
Int     Severity
0       Emergency
1       Alert
2       Critical
3       Error
4       Warning
5       Notice
6       Informational
7       Debug

Int     Facility
0       kernel messages
1       user-level messages
2       mail system
3       system daemons
4       security/authorization messages
5       internal
6       line printer subsystem
7       network news subsystem
8       UUCP subsystem
9       clock daemon
10      security/authorization messages
11      FTP daemon
12      NTP subsystem
13      log audit
14      log alert
15      clock daemon
16      local0
17      local1
18      local2
19      local3
20      local4
21      local5
22      local6
23      local7
```

The format of the outputted text may be any style you like, as long as it retains its human readable characteristics.

**Examples**

```
mail system, Critical\n

mail system\n
Critical\n

mail system - Critical\n

mail system Critical\n
```

**Example**

Given a `PRI` value of 103, your program must output:

```
NTP Subsystem, Debug
```

The shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: I don't see any glaring issues, though it isn't particularly interesting (outputting strings based on a lookup table has been done multiple times).

Comment: Do you happen to have any suggestions that would make it more appealing? Also, Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## Build a Markdown to HTML converter

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)
The Stack Exchange network uses Markdown as the syntax for writing posts. For example, using a # at the beginning of a line creates a heading (`<h1>`) while two hashes ## creates a subheading (`<h2>`).
Your task is to write a program which takes input as a syntactically valid Markdown string and outputs its HTML equivalent. (This program might find use as a means to transfer SE posts to one's own website.)
The only Markdown "commands" you need to support are the backtick (becomes a tag named `code`, styling provided), the hashes (# becomes `h1`, ## becomes `h2` and ### becomes `h3`), and the `>` (blockquote). The rest may be left intact.

For example, if the input is

```
# Some text
## Part 1
Lorem `ipsum` dolor sit amet
> consectetur adispicing
```

Then the output should be

```
<h1>Some text</h1>
<h2>Part 1</h1>
Lorem <code>ipsum</code> dolor sit amet
<blockquote>consectetur adispicing</blockquote>
```

Leading spaces are acceptable for the headings as they are mandatory in Markdown, but trailing spaces are not (you may assume the input has no trailing spaces). Except for the inline `code`, all commands will be displayed as blocks and will be on separate lines. For example

```
# Some text ## Another
```

is not a valid input because there is a block command on the same line as another block command.
You may assume that the input contains no `<` or `>` except for blockquote notation, you must also follow the guidelines exactly, so no outputting HTML which renders the same result but in a different way.

Second test case:

```
### Subheading
> This is some heading with `code` in it.
```

becomes

```
<h3>Subheading</h3>
<blockquote>This is some heading with <code>code</code> in it.</blockquote>
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: HTML use `<code>` instead of `<shortsnippet>`. Are you defining yet another target language?

Comment: May I assume input will never contains `<>` other than block quote notation? Or, what should I do if input contains one? For example, for input `3 < 2`, should I yield something like `3 &lt; 2`?

Comment: @tsh Oops, didn't know about that one, editing that in. You may assume that the input will never contain `<` or `>` except for blockquote notation.

Comment: "but trailing spaces are not" should I assume the input will not contains trailing spaces too? or should i strip spaces at end of inputs when i generate html? Does this only apply to space (U+0020) or any whitespace characters?

Comment: Should I output exactly same string as example output? Or may I output something HTML may render same results?

Comment: Will the code ever contain unmatched backticks on a line?

Answer (score 0):

## SSD optimize

Given \$n\$ pages, each page containing \$m\$ sectors, write three functions: (Here `x` and `y` are sectors)

1. `insert(x)` that stores the input(temporary sector) into a sector,
2. `remove(x)` that removes one, and
3. `get(x)` that return a sector containing the element.

You can call these functions:

1. `copy(y,x)` that copy a sector from `x` to `y`, and
2. `clear(x)` that clears the page containing `x`, can only be called \$k\$ times for each page.

There'll never be more than(can equal to) \$p\%mn\$ elements required to store. Your score is the numbers of call before you fail. Everyone can provide test case for any program.

\$n=256, m=16, p=75, k=100\$.

For example, if a solution don't do any clear and just place inputs into \$(1,1), (1,2), \cdots, (n,m)\$, someone else can write and remove till you use up all space:

```
insert\*3072, (delete, insert)*1025, get
```

The last `get` can't get anything and is a fail, so the score is 5122.

Highest score wins. Robber's winning criticia TODO.

Comment: I work with SSD firmware as my job. I just wanted to point out a real story: it is a real PITA to optimize SSD lifetime depending on the user workload. The relevant components include multiple dozen C files, each file being up to tens of kilobytes. The algorithms involved have been accumulated for over a decade, and are still evolving. (This doesn't mean the challenge is inherently bad, as we can explore possible optimizations at the amateur level, which is interesting in its own right.)

Comment: It is somewhat unclear how \$p=75\$ is applied in the `insert\*3072, (delete, insert)*1025, get` workload. Did you mean 75% of the entire space? (in which case \$p=3072\$ or \$p=0.75mn\$ would be more accurate)

Comment: @Bubbler the `%` is missing

Comment: For the winning criteria: you could make it a single-challenge CnR ([like this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37797/78410)). Initially, a cop posts a submission with their own estimate of the score. Then a robber tries to reduce the cops' scores by finding worse scenarios, and the robber takes the reduced score as their own score. A cop with the highest final score wins; a robber with the highest "robbed" total score wins. (Check out more specific rules in the linked challenge)

Comment: You should really add some background story to your question. Currently, I cannot understand anything in it. What are pages? What are sectors? How are these 5 functions works? What does `clear` mean? And why should I `clear` it? What does `get` do? Am I designed to storage some data between each invokes?

Comment: Your example \$ (1,1), (1,2), \cdots, (n,m) \$ is a list with 4096 elements in it. Won't it run up after 4096 iterations? What is 5122 here? Are \$ n=256, m=16, p=75, k=100 \$ some given parameter to these 3 functions?

Comment: @tsh It's a promise that you don't store more than `n*m*p%` datas, so when reaching 3072 you have to erase some, adding movements

Answer (score 0):

## 2D Pathfinding with Momentum

[Posted to main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221194/2d-pathfinding-with-momentum)

Answer (score 0):

[Finding Distant Primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221073/finding-distant-primes)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why is 23 a 9-distant prime when |2⁴ - 23| = 7. Why did you raise 2 to specifically the fifth power? Or is both, and also a 22, 21, 19, 15, 7, 9, 41, etc... distant prime?

Comment: @Medix2 yes it is all of those.

Answer (score 0):

Output a random pair of twin primes. Every pair should possibly appear and the program should have zero possibility to fall into infinite loop. Notice that we don't know if there are infinite many pairs so you need some fallbacks to avoid finding a not-existing pair.

Comment: Define twin primes

Answer (score 0):

## Add trailing whitespace [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Sometimes, we accidentally have trailing whitespace in test cases, and some helpful person notices and fixes that. Thank you, helpful people.

But what if we want to take a string without trailing whitespace and add some?

Your challenge is to write a program that takes a string as input and adds between 1 and 10 spaces (randomly) to the end of each line.

### Rules

Between 1 and 10 (inclusive) spaces (`" "`)  must be added to each line. There must be a nonzero chance of getting any number of spaces on any line.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins.

Apologies if this already exists - It's really hard to search.

Comment: "just **before** each newline and the end of file" "**trailing** whitespace"?

Comment: @tsh Sorry for being confusing. Rewrote. Is this a good challenge?

Comment: Maybe to make the challenge a bit harder require an additional line to the file with random number of spaces, because then less trivial answers

Answer (score 0):

Given a black-box function `f(x)` which take a value `x` and output `true` for \$p(x)\$, an unknown continious monotone function(not knowing even whether it's increasing), probable; and `false` otherwise. Output an infinite sequence \$a_n\$ such that \$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p(a_n)=0.5\$. You can assume that the result exists.

Reasonable I/O allowed. Shortest code win.

A possible solution:

```
for i=1..infty
    S = [i/2] * i*i*2
    for j=0..i*i*2-1
        for k=1..i
            if f(j/i-i)
                S[j]--
    print minPos([t*t for t in S])/i-i
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##XZDLDoIwEEX3fMVNXFgaH8DSyFe4JCwwLTooLSnFwNdjWzQSZ9FJ5uTcybSb7F2rbKa208bCVEroNhKyRs3G@BTBlZF2MOrDDktj8XmcSdV2Qo40SbBBr0EWQstebV3SoFBrI1/SRK6DQCHiJlm6C@In/eICCjpmJTgYceJZHOZean7SQhblix8rvEK@yB@QHhLeHGn/D8Paoilz/@zTwDpDysIbvfsIKdh67Q4POeXPqr2KCs3Ja9yNi6T06fP8Bg)

[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: So we are given two functions `f` and `p` and need to define an infinite sequence?

Comment: You're not given `p`, and you're to find `a` such that `p(a)=0.5`

Comment: If we are not given `p`, how are we supposed to find `a`? Do you want us to generate an `a` that works for every `p`?

Comment: @Quelklef Try some `a` and adjust till probable is 0.5

Comment: I completely do not understand. Is it possible you could provide an example solution in your problem? That may help others confused like me.

Comment: Say, \$ p\left(x\right) = \frac{4\pi + 2\arctan\left(x\right)}{5\pi} \$. How can you find out such a sequence \$ a_n \$ let \$ \lim_{n\to\infty}p(a_n)=0.5 \$

Comment: Even if we can safely assume that there _is_ a value \$x\$ that \$p\left(x\right)=0.5\$, I don't think anyone can provide sequence would even convergent with a non-zero probable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222676)

Answer (score 0):

## [Equalizing fractions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222725/equalizing-fractions)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## Count What You See [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

You may have heard of the [Look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence), which is generated by reading off the digits of previous entries in the sequence. Here, you will be tasked to generate the "Count-and-say sequence".

In general, the sequence can be generated as follows:

1. Start with an arbitrary sequence of numbers (e.g. `1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2`).
2. Count the occurrences of each number as `adjective noun` pairs -> `"four 1, one 3, two 2"`, in order of *1st appearance*. In the example, this means that you must first count `1s`, then `3s`, then `2s`, since that is the order in which the numbers first appear in the sequence.
3. Write out the result from step 2 numerically (`"four 1, one 3, two 2" -> 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2`).
4. Append the result from step 3 to the original sequence to get `1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2`.
5. Repeat the steps above to continue the sequence.

### Task

Your task is to output the "Count-and-say sequence", such that the sequence starts with `1`.  You may choose to:

- Take an input \$ n \$ and output the first \$ n \$ integers.
- Take an input \$ n \$ and output the \$ n \$-th integer.
- Output the sequence indefinitely.

For convenience, here are the first 100 numbers in the sequence (also [A217780](https://oeis.org/A217780)):

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2, 11, 1, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 8, 13, 1, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2, 2, 8, 1, 11, 1, 5, 16, 1, 10, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8, 2, 11, 3, 5, 1, 13, 18, 1, 12, 3, 9, 4, 6, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 3, 11, 4, 5, 2, 13, 1, 16, 1, 10, 1, 7, 22, 1, 14, 3, 11
```

Answer (score 0):

## Node one-liner to fetch a URL, like curl

I'm interested in the shortest one-liner to output the contents at a given URL, using Node.js from the command line, for practical purposes. In other words, the equivalent of `curl`, written as a Node one-liner.

Not interested in other languages. Would this respect the site's rules, or does it belong on SO?

Rules:

1. The URL is passed via the command line, so accessed via `process.argv[1]`
2. Must invoke node with the `-e` argument, followed by the code, followed by the URL
3. Only the length of the actual script passed to node via `-e "..."` is counted.

My best solution so far, with `http://x.com` as a conveniently short example, is:

```sh
node -r got -e "require('got')(process.argv[1]).then(r=>console.log(r.body))" http://x.com
```

Comment: You can make it a tips question

Answer (score 0):

**Program**-Write a program to display repeating terms of a given sentence.

**Explanation**-the program must output the repeating terms of two or more letters from the given input(input is a sentence seperated be spaces without any punctuation except the full-stop indicating the end.) For example, if input is the sentence "I **am** **an** **am**eture **ma**the**ma**gici**an**" the outupt must be am, ma, an. ( not that em is not a valid output as it is separated by space)

**Example-**

input->International competitions are better than intercollege ones.

output-> Inter, ti, er, tion, io,on,ion, tio, co, on,.......etc
(t, l must not be included as they are 1 letter.) (Upper lower Cases do not matter)

**Test cases-**

input-> aabcde cdec

output-> cde, cd, de

input-> aab aacab

output-> aa, ab

input-> aaa aabcaaa ababa

output-> aaa, aa, ab, aba, ba

**Winning Criterion**:- code golf

Comment: You say tt and ll aren't included, but then have aa as an example output. Also, what if two things overlap? In ababa, is aba included?

Comment: Thanx edited accordingly.

Comment: Is the input always going to contain at least 1 space? And can input be taken as a list of words (e.g. `['aab', 'aacab']`) instead of a space-separated string? Additionally, I'd suggest mentioning something about the case of the input. For example, case-wise, your example (`International ...`) only has `inter` repeated if case is ignored

Answer (score 0):

## Getting to the root of the problem

While I was sleeping in my bed, unwilling to wake up, an idea entered my head: why is the syntax for powers, especially roots, so cumbersome? It would save so many bytes if we could just use the square root symbol instead, and easier to understand too. So, your challenge is to encode this in whatever format you choose, in as few bytes possible.

Answers should be able to:

a) convert a string such as `2**(1/2)` into `√2` or some other format that distinguishes it from `2√2` (note, if you choose to write `2√2` as `2 * √2` and write things like `2**(1/3)` as `3√2`, that is allowed).

b) Work for arbitrary powers (`2**(1/50)` should work fine).

c) Simplify roots. (`4**(1/4)` = `√2`)

and should be able to perform this on inputted strings.

Deduct 10% from your score if you can handle addition of roots, deduct a further 10% off that if you can handle the ret of the basic operators (-, *, /), another 10% if you can simplify expressions such as `(2 - √2)/(2 + √2)`, another 10% if you can write `16**1/4` (for example) as `√(2^2)`, and, if you're amazing enough to implement exponentiation, you can subtract 50%.

Input will be presented in the form of `[0-9]**([0-9]/[0-9])`, where the 0-9s can be any number of digits.
Output should ideally be in the form of `[0-9] * [0-9]√[0-9]`, again, with the 0-9s being any number of digits, but I will let other forms slide so long as as `3√2` (that's the cube root of 2) is distinguishable from `3 * √2`.

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Lowest score wins.
Good luck!

Comment: This is a good challenge, at least part A looks good, but it will need to be clarified. Ideally put a regex that objectively tells what input we need to handle (like whether we should handle whitespace (which we probably shouldn't have to)). The bonuses are most likely unnescessary.

Comment: The bonuses might be unnecessary, but if someone can write a creative answer that does all of that, it'd probably be an even better answer than one that just does the minimum, and might score lower (I was generous with the bonuses to encourage going the extra mile, and you can get a reduction of over 70% from them). About the input, I'll fix that now.

Comment: Also this is going to be important to my tie-in puzzle, "Returning to the root of the problem", and having those bonuses done now will improve your overall score (yes this may well be a series).

Comment: Should 72**(1/6) be 2V2*3V3?

Comment: You can do it as such if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

## Computer Tree

Consider an infinite amount of same computers building a tree, running same program. Each computer has infinite memory and infinite pins 0 to Infinity, where pin 0 connect to its parent, or the IO we see for the root; and pin 1..Inf connect to its childs.

Each connection is bidirectional, and has buffer in each direction. Writer put the value into buffer, and reader gets from it.

The computers need to support these abilities: (Here dest is a variable in the memory, and src1, src2 are either variable or immediate integers. [x] mean the memory in address x.

```
dest = src1 op src2, op in +,-,*
[dest] = src1
dest = [src1]
if(src1 op src2) goto inst, op in <,==,<=,!=
if((not)pin src1 writing) goto inst
if((not)pin src1 reading) goto inst
write src2 to pin src1, block if already writing
read dest from pin src1, block if not reading
```

It's fine if you need several elements to do one job above, but each job defined above should use same amount of time(In this model timing matters). It's also fine if you take input as some other formats, but to avoid taking too ready functions, an same-type input shouldn't lead to an infinite loop. Input for root is given when started and will never need to wait unless all input used up, but it doesn't always halt.

Shortest code win.

Answer (score 0):

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion)

## Interpret a Cangjie Input Method String

The [Cangjie input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cangjie_input_method) is a method for inputting Chinese characters using a standard QWERTY-like keyboard. Each Chinese character is encoded as a sequence of Latin letters, each letter representing a radical, or part, of the character's form. Each letter encodes both the radical character it represents, as well as other, related radicals (such as `E` encoding `水` as well as `氵`, and more).

There are 24 radicals encoded in Cangjie, as well as 3 other characters for wild cards and other purposes. For the purposes of this challenge, only the subset of the main 4 groups are used, shown below with meanings:

```
Philosophical group
A   日 sun
B   月 moon
C   金 gold
D   木 wood
E   水 water
F   火 fire
G   土 land

Stroke group
H   竹 bamboo
I   戈 dagger axe
J   十 ten
K   大 big
L   中 centre
M   一 one
N   弓 bow

Body parts group
O   人 person
P   心 heart
Q   手 hand
R   口 mouth

Character shapes group
S   尸 corpse
T   廿 twenty
U   山 mountain
V   女 woman
W   田 field
Y   卜 fortune telling
```

### Cangjie Basic Rules

Characters are analyzed as such to create a Cangjie code (based on the Wikipedia article above):

- Direction of decomposition: left to right, top to bottom, outside to inside
- Geometrically connected forms: takes 4 Cangjie codes from the 1st code to the last code
- Geometrically unconnected forms:
- - Forms in exactly 2 subforms: Follow the direction of decomposition rules, then take the first and last codes of of the first subform, and the first, second, and last code of the second subform.
- - Forms in more than 2 subforms: take the first and last codes of the first subform according to direction of decomposition, then break the remainder into subforms. Take the first and last codes of the first remainder, and the last code of the last remainder.

### The Challenge

Write a full program or function that, when given a valid Cangjie code string as input, outputs its corresponding traditional Chinese character.

### Additional Rules

- Use Cangjie version 5.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- An invalid Cangjie code string (not in our subset of codes) is undefined behavior when used as input.
- If multiple characters match a Cangjie code string, you can choose to output both, or choose one. If you choose one, it must only output that character when given that code.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

### Examples

```
Input - Output (notes)
JWJ - 車 (connected, top to bottom: 十田十)
YRHHI - 謝 (3 parts: first is disconnected, take first and last YR;
           second is is disconnected, take first and last HH; last part take last I)
AN - 門 (special case: fixed decomposition)
OMN - 气 (another fixed decomposition; using version 5)
A - 日
BOB - 肭
JPHI - 蜜
GUMPC - 顤
STKR - 匿 or  (if multiple characters exist for that code, pick one deterministically)
HXH - (undefined behavior, since X is not in the set of codes above)
```

### Meta

- Is it clear? Anything that needs adding/removing?
- Any weird test cases I didn't put in?
- Anything else?

Comment: It's not clear enough how to actually do the conversion (without looking at the Wikipedia article). Remember to always assume no pre-existing subject knowledge when writing challenges, and don't require users to use external resources to find out about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Text in aLtErNaTiNg cApS

Sometimes, we want to convey sarcasm in a text message or in a YouTube/Reddit comment. To this end, "alternating caps" is often used. Your task, should you wish to accept it, is to write code that turns the input text into its "alternating caps" version.

> (This is a **deleted** rule. You should ignore this for the challenge) For most sans-serif web fonts, it is hard to distinguish capital I (for India) and lower-case l (for Lima). So we want to avoid either of these letters in our output. To achieve this, we are allowed to sacrifice "exact alternating-ness" of the output. Details below.

### Input:

1. A string of words involving [a-zA-Z], with one space in between each word.
2. You may not assume whether or not the string ends with a space/newline/etc.

### Output:

1. The input, turned into "alternating caps form", with the first letter of each word being lower-case.
2. > (**Deleted**; you should not implement it. I have included it just to illustrate my thought process) You may not output any capital I (`I`, for India) or lower-case l (`l`, for Lima). To avoid these, you may continue outputting the same letter-case as the previous letter, but you must switch the letter-case at the earliest possible instance. (note to self: this requirement means there are sometimes more than two letters of the same case, which I don't really want)
3. Non-suppressible output can be ignored.

### Rules:

1. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
2. You must take input from and output to natural places, according to your language.
3. This is `code-golf`, so the lowest byte-count wins. Ties are broken by earliest submission.
4. Please provide a way for readers to test your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
5. An ungolfed version and an explanation for your code is appreciated, although not required for the challenge.

## Examples

```
Input -> Output
---------------
alternating -> aLtErNaTiNg
lower case letters -> lOwEr cAsE lEtTeRs
```

Examples that follow the **deleted** rule (which you should not implement -- these are just for your interest:

> I used [dcode](https://www.dcode.fr/word-search-regexp) to find some of these examples.
> `holding -> hOLdiNg`
> `radii -> rAdii (has more than 2 lower-cases in a row, if using my rules)`
> `fall -> fALL (has more than 2 capitals in a row, if using my rules)`
> `volleyball -> [even if you are allowed to change the previous letter-cases to try to stop 'ALL' (3 capitals in a row) from appearing, there is a non-unique way of doing so]`

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this has been posted before: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122783

Comment: @pxeger That challenge is slightly different, as this one asks for alternating characters rather than alternating *letters*. `lower case letters` in that challenge would become `LoWeR cAsE lEtTeRs` (or `lOwEr CaSe LeTtErS`), neither of which are acceptable outputs for this

Answer (score 0):

[Fastest unique finder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223431)

Answer (score 0):

Take two registers, zero-extend one to another one on x64 in a single instruction.

Here, registers are `r0-r15`(64-bit), `r0d-r15d`(32-bit), `r0w-r15w`(16-bit) and `r0b-r15b`(8-bit), where regs marking same number share same lowest part. In case there's no solution (e.g. writing into r0d, which the opcode would behave writing to r0), output something obviously not an opcode.

Opcodes:

```
90              do nothing
89 11sssddd     move 16/32/64-bit[1] from sss[2] to ddd[2]
88 11sssddd     move 8-bit from sss[2] to ddd[2]
0F B7 11dddsss  move from 16-bit sss[2] to 32/64-bit[1] ddd[2]
0F B6 11dddsss  move from 8-bit sss[2] to 16/32/64-bit[1] ddd[2]
101101dd 00     move from 8-bit 0dd[2] to 16-bit 0dd[2]             
[WIP]
```

Shortest code win. -35 Bytes if you support `ax cx dx bx sp bi sp di` aliasing `r0w-r7w`, and `rax-rdi` as `r0-r7`, `eax-edi` as `r0d-r7d`; - another 35 Bytes if you support `al cl dl bl` aliasing `r0b-r3b` and `ah ch dh bh` as theoretically `r4b-r7b` but without REXs.

Answer (score 0):

## Make an image with the pixels from another (WIP)

[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

---

Given a target image and a source image, output an image that resembles the target image by rearranging the pixels of the source image.

You will be scored based on speed and accuracy.

$$
score = {similarity(Image_{target}, Image_{result}) \times {time_{reference} \over time_{program}}}
$$

Higher scores are better

Answer (score 0):

On a 150x150 area, each cell have 15% probable of being a mine. Opening a safe(non-mine) cell tells you amount of mines with <1.5 distance. Opening a mine makes you fail. Find most safe cells in 5 second.

Comment: This isn't very well specified. How will the grid be given, and will it be given via interactive I/O or do we need to provide a function that will be called multiple times? How will this be timed? Will testing be done via a fixed sample? Also, I am pretty sure that any reasonable implementation (doesn't even need extreme optimizations) will be able to clear an entire 150x150 board in well under 5 seconds.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino What about 1500x1500? Giving grid method quite flexible

Answer (score 0):

## [Non-Hamming numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223789/non-hamming-numbers)

Comment: I would suggest including a definition of hamming (or non-hamming) numbers in the challenge description.

Comment: You definitely need to define non-hamming numbers - challenges should never require you to look at an outside source (the challenge you linked should too), and I would suggest providing a detailed example of how to compute them as well. Also, add the [tag:sequence] tag.

Answer (score 0):

## [Largest Compatible Maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224109/largest-compatible-maze)

Answer (score 0):

## Packing numbers to interval

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Interval notation is a way to write complicated range bounds more conveniently and concisely than writing an inequality.

Like a list `1, 2, 3, 4` can be written like `[1,4]`.

There have been already challenges on interpreting interval notations to number ranges, but now we will do the reverse.

Some examples (test cases):

- Input will be a list of numbers (can be positive, negative, 0, but not fractions)
- Input list can be unsorted
- If there is gap between the numbers (I mean in a list like `1,2,5,6`, `3,4` is missing), you have to write multiple intervals seperate by Union sign (`U`)
- There will be no leading 0s in input numbers
- If there is only one number seperate in an interval (I mean like `2` in the list of `2,5,6,7`) then make a seperate interval (for the example `[2]U[5,7]`
- The intervals should go from smallest to largest (for example `1 2 5 6`, `[1,2]U[5,6]` is valid but `[5,6]U[1,2]` not.
- Input numbers can be separated by anything, it is up to you.

```
1 2 3 4 -> [1,4]
5 3 4 1 2 -> [1,5]
2 1 6 5 -> [1,2]U[5,6]
6 7 9 8 -4 -2 -3 0 2 1 -> [-2,-4]U[-0,2]U[6,9]
```

Standard loopholes apply, shortest code wins.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52321/determine-ranges-from-a-list-of-values)?

Comment: @Leo hmmm... i think its really a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

## Two player tic-tac-toe game

Create a Tic-Tac-Toe game that allows two human players to play against each other.

- The drawn board can be either in ASCII or graphical (You can use 1-9 digits as a place holder in tic tac toe board)
- Program should randomly choose whose turn is first and randomly give two players X or O
- let both users know whose turn it is amd prompt for input
- Check for winning, and when one player is won, let them both know about win (same for draw game)
- Enforce all tic-tac-toe rules

Standard loopholes apply, shortest code wins

Answer (score 0):

Given a table(2D array of strings), arrange width of each column to shorten total width, such that containment in each cell can be fully shown with a space after it, being allowed to occupy next several cells if they are empty. In another word, for each column provide a width \$W_j\$, making \$\sum_jW_j\$ smallest, and for each non-empty cell in column \$i\$ , if there're \$k\$ empty cells on adjacent right, then its length is smaller than \$\sum_{j=i}^{i+k}W_j\$.

Samples:

```
"1234", ""  => [2,3] "1234 
"a"   , "b"           a b  "

"Date"  , ""  , "Sum"            "Date   Sum
"Mar"   , "1" , "220"             Mar 1  220
"Mar"   , "15", "130" => [4,3,4]  Mar 15 130
"Apr"   , "3" , "100"             Apr 3  100
"Sum_Up", ""  , "450"             Sum_Up 450 "

"aaa" ""    ""               "aaa
""    "bbb" ""    => [0,0,4]  bbb
""    ""    "ccc"             ccc"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hamming Distance Lookup Extravaganza

> Note: I was originally just going to post this, but I was having trouble coming up with a good scoring strategy. I'd like to make sure that the instructions are clear and scoring strategy is fair and works. Thanks!

> Note: This question is a WIP, and some parts may be incomplete or in the middle of editing!

### Story

Bitty Benny runs a clothing factory, where, among other things, he produces bundles of shirts. Each shirt has a *tag* (don't worry, it's not itchy) describing what type of shirt it is.

Similar shirts have similar tags, and Bitty Benny wants to create an organization system, that, given a tag, will fetch the shirt with the most similar tag. Each tag is the same length, and lists a series of ones and zeros. To compare how similar tags are, Bitty Benny bought a [Hamming Shirt Comparator (Mark II)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). Here's a loose schematic as to how the comparator works:

1. First, the Comparator takes the two tags and lays them side by side, like so:

   ```
   +----------+
   | 10010100 |
   +----------+
   | 00101101 |
   +----------+
   ```
2. Then, the comparator goes through each pair of numbers and counts the number of differences:

   ```
   +----------+
   | 10000100 |
   +-|---|--|-+
   | 00001101 |
   +-|---|--|-+
     x   x  x : 3 differences
   ```
3. The comparator then laser-engraves the difference onto a marble stone tablet. Some argue that the Mark I was better, because it printed out results instead, but Bitty Benny likes the satisfying thunk of the tablet as it falls from the machine.

The lower the number the comparator outputs, the more similar the shirts are. A perfect match has a score of 0, an imperfect one has a score of the length of the tag.

Bitty Benny has a lot of impatient (but well-paying) clients who demand specific types of shirts. **How can Bitty Benny organize and search through the shirts to find the closest-matching tag as quickly as possible?**

### Formal Definition

A tag is a bit-vector of size *N*, where N is a power of two. For this particular challenge we'll assume N to be 64.

> Hint: On modern CPU architectures, a tag can be represented by a word (an unsigned 64-bit integer), and the difference between two tags can be written as an `xor` then a [`popcount`](https://vaibhavsagar.com/blog/2019/09/08/popcount/) (count the number of ones in the binary representation of the integer). This distance is generally referred to as the *hamming Distance* (lowercase 'h', of course) between two words.

Naïvely, using a linear search, finding a tag will take *O(n)* time. Faster solutions exist - can you find them?

#### Input

Your program will take two inputs:

1. A list of random tags.
2. a different list of target tags.

These lists may be of different sizes. The input format will be as follows:

```
<Size of random tags list>
<tag as a decimal number `0 <= n < 2^64`>
...
<Size of random target tags list>
<tag as a decimal number>
...
```

The competition input has been generated, and can be found here.

#### Task

**For each target tag, determine the closest match in the random tag list, using hamming Distance as described above.**

> In the case of a tie, i.e. multiple tags have the same minimum distance, any one is valid.

#### Output

In the order of reading, print out the closest match of each tag as a number, in the appropriate base.

### Scoring and Rules

The goals of this competition are to find solutions that are:

1. Fast, in terms of execution time.
2. Clever, in terms of algorithm used, amortized cost, and write-up.

To score your program:

> Note: I have to finish writing example baseline program
> Note: I have to generate and upload the testing list. Ideally it should be big enough that the naive solution takes around 3 seconds on a modern computer.

1. Translate this naïve idiomatic program from Rust to your language of choice.
2. Time the naïve solution in your language of choice.
3. Write an optimized solution in the same language, and time it using the same technique.
4. **Your score is the optimized execution time, in seconds + that times the speedup, lower scores are better:**

   ```
   score = fast_time +  ((fast_time ** 2) / slow_time)
   ```

Time your programs using `time`, include the time taken for I/O.

> Note:
> This scoring method is good for two reasons:
>
> 1. In the case that there is no speedup compared to the baseline, the score is just 2x the time.
> 2. Any speedups over the base version will decrease the score, but the score will never be less than the wall-clock time it takes.

To determine the answer with the best writeup, we'll also be running a popularity contest.

### Entry Template

I'm no stickler, but here's a loose entry template if you'd like to keep things consistent:

````
## <Language> <Speed Score> (<Calculation>)
<Link to idiomatic solution>
```
<Optimized entry>
<If over a respectable size, put a link here instead>
```

## How it works
<breakdown of the code>
<and the method used>
<and any other interesting notes>
````

Good luck, and happy tagging! Bitty Benny awaits your entry!

Answer (score 0):

## Participant number

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

A math Olympiad will be held, and participants are being registered. The highest number of participants is 100. Each participant is given an ID number. It is given in a sequence like \$100, 97, 94, 91, 88, ...., 1\$, and when the first sequence is over, then \$99, 96, 93, 90, 87, ...., 3\$ sequence and so on.

Let's assume one of the participant's ID number is \$k\$ and he/she is the \$n^{th}\$ participant. Given the value of \$k\$, return the value of \$n\$.

**Test Cases**

```
59 -> 81
89 -> 71
16 -> 29
26 -> 92
63 -> 47
26 -> 92
45 -> 53
91 -> 4
18 -> 62
19 -> 28
```

There will be no leading zero in input. Standard   loopholes apply, shortest code wins. In output there can be trailing whitespace.

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64667/josephus-problem-with-three-inputs?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

Given a string *s*, find a string *t*, containing only printable ASCII characters (32-126), such that [PPCG53675](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/)(*t*)=*s*. You can assume such string exist.

Examples:

- `tmop` => `test` (and 23 other possible outputs)
- `TEST` => `T5oV` (and 23 other possible outputs)
- `!!!!` => `!!!!` (and 17)
- `!!`   => `!`    (only one solution)
- `~}}~` => `~|~~` (only one solution)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms How? `ac` is not a valid output for `ac`

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that it can be multiple characters.

Comment: It might be harder than it sounds (at least to solve efficiently), as there are edge cases involving values close to 32 and 126. Looks like a good challenge, though it needs some good test cases. Also needs a self-contained description.

Answer (score 0):

Extract json, with only few bytes.

Extract the "name" of each dictionary in the json list.

You are allowed to use any package which can be installed on Ubuntu 20.04.

Example json:

```
[
    {
        "id":"d963984c-1075-4d25-8cd0-eae9a7e2d130",
    "extra": {
        "foo": false,
        "bar": null
    },
    "created_at":"2020-05-06T15:31:59Z",
    "name": "NAME1"
    },
    {
    "id":"ee63984c-1075-4d25-8cd0-eae9a7e2d1xx",
    "name": "NAME2"
    }
    ]
```

This script would work:

```
import json
import sys

for item in json.loads(sys.stdin.read()):
    print(item['name'])
```

Desired output:

```
NAME1
NAME2
```

But since I am very lazy, I am looking for a solution which needs less characters.

The solution with the minimal number of bytes wins.

Using non-ascii characters is not allowed.

Compressing into base64 or similar is not allowed. The solution should be "type-able" by a human.

---

Since the question does not fit ot code-gold, I published it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194693/filter-json-on-the-command-line

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for using the sandbox. Note that, by default, we count code in number of bytes, not number of characters, to prevent abuse like compressing code into Unicode characters that might need up to 4 bytes each.

Comment: @Adám I updated the question. It should be type-able. Do you think it is ok now?

Comment: Why prohibit non-ascii characters? I can certainly type non-ascii characters on my keyboard, and I'm human.

Comment: Why prohibit compression? If that gives me a better score, then why not use that?

Comment: I'd use the word "extract" rather than "filter", since we're not reducing the number of dictionaries. Rather, we're extracting the "name" member of each.

Comment: @Adám I search for a solution which I could easily apply in the future again. I need to extract data from json from time to time and I am searching for a pattern which I can re-use. That's why compression (like gzip/base64/...) makes no sense to me. I want the solution to be readable and more or less easy to understand. Maybe "bytes" is the wrong unit for what I want.

Comment: I think your challenge is interesting and has potential, but please do not try to use this site as a place to get programming help. For that, try Stack Overflow instead. Be warned that people here will break all best practices and accept extreme inefficiency to save a single byte. If you try to circumvent this culture (which is the purpose of the site!) then you will be met with what can be perceived as hostility.

Comment: Even though you've posted on SE, do you want to sort this out as a proper code golf challenge for this site too?

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck to ESOPUNKS

Brainfuck use 8 instructions

```
byte(or bigint, your choose) a[inf]; bigint i;
+  ++a[i];
-  --a[i];
,  a[i]=getchar();
.  putchar(a[i]);
[  while(a[i]){
]  }
<  if(--i<0) undefined_behavior();
>  ++i;
```

[ESOPUNKS](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ESOPUNK) have two registers `X` and `T`, two I/O ports `#STDI`(stdin, read like how brainfuck does), and `#STDO`(stdout, undefined behavior if written <0 or >255), use these instructions:

```
COPY a b     b=a; a,b,c can be X,T,#STDI,#STDO or integer as long as it makes sense(no giving integer a value, etc.)
ADDI a b c   c=b+a;
SUBI a b c   c=b-a;
MULI a b c   c=b*a;
DIVI a b c   c=b/a; Halt if a=0
MODI a b c   c=b%a; Halt if a=0
MARK label   label:
JUMP label   goto label;
TJMP label   if(T) goto label;
FJMP label   if(!T) goto label;
TEST a op b  T = (a op b); op = <, =(==), >
HALT         exit(0)
```

(Didn't cover all instructions from esolangs as some are not implemented in the interperter)

Now write a program that converts a Brainfuck program into a ESOPUNKS one. Your ESOPUNKS output should have O(1) lines.

Note:

- It's possible to convert. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine) shows a proof that applies with small removal.
- It's possible for bounded lines to store unbounded info as unbounded integer behave as operator
- Outputting may need a snippet repeating 256 times to allow any possible output; However I don't care length of output(as long as it's bounded), and the repeating can be generated with small code, so this shouldn't matter much.

Code-golf, shortest code in the language wins.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding some aspect, this is unreasonably hard. Converting between a TM (brainfuck) and a 2 counter machine (Esopunks), while possible, has a lot of caveats that are delineated by the wiki page you linked, most relevantly that the input has to be given as an initialization of one of the counters as an integer encoding a TM. Then the actual conversion algorithm between TM and 2CM is *also* extremely involved, not least of which includes encoding 4 counters in one via the prime factorization \$2^a3^b5^c7^d\$. This is closer to a thesis project than a code golf...

Answer (score 0):

## Generate a uncomputable number

An uncomputable number is a number that some digit can't be computed in finite time.

Now you're to generate and output one of them.

You can(and need to) use `\b` to undo an outputted byte, but every byte should stop changing from some time.

An example solution, assuming `stepN(p, n)` checks if program `p` halts in `n` steps, returning 0 or 1:

```
s = [];
output('0.');
for (i=1; ; ++i) {
    t = [stepN(j, i) for j in [1,n]]
    while (s is not a prefix of t) {
        output('\b');
        s.remove_last();
    }
    for (j=s.length; j<t.length; ++j) {
        s.insert_to_last(t[j]);
        output(t[j]);
    }
} // 0.s[0]s[1]s[2]s[3]..., s[i] mean if program i halt
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Where does your definition of "uncomputable number" come from? What I'm familiar with is "a number defined in terms of [uncomputably fast-growing function](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Computable_function)".

Comment: I can imagine that a slight modification of the challenge would work using my definition: Pick an uncomputable function `f(n)`. Given `n` as input, output an infinite sequence of numbers, which should eventually produce an infinite stream of `f(n)` and nothing else. A possible answer in this case is a BF busy-beaver function, where you run each step of all syntactically valid BF programs of length n and update the answer whenever one of them halts.

Comment: @Bubbler Defined as "not [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number)"

Comment: Then I guess you should include in the first sentence that you want a *real* number, as opposed to an integer. I could find only one uncomputable real number, [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant), which is a halting probability of a random program (in a hypothetical programming language with a specific property). Also, IMHO erasing digits with `\b` is superfluous and unnecessary, and you should allow outputting infinite stream of digit strings (and allow printing or returning them).

Comment: Also, should the number be output in decimal, or can I output it in binary or other base?

Comment: @Bubbler If an expressing is uncomputable in binary, it is for decimal

Comment: @Bubbler If you don't use `\b` then it's not uncomputable

Comment: I mean, if I want to revise an earlier digit, I can print a new number instead of overwriting the number.

Comment: @Bubbler You mean the output method of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20921/)?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0):

## Write a fast-growing assembly function

### Synopsis

Your goal is to implement the (asymptotically) fastest growing function within bounded code on a fictional CPU utilizing a quite limited, yet (probably) turing-complete instruction set.

### Environment

The CPU utilizes unbounded RAM as well as two registers, the accumulator A and the program counter C, with words consisting of arbitrary integers, such that neither overflows nor underflows are possible. RAM is used to store data as well as code, allowing for self-modifying programs. Each instruction takes one parameter and therefore consists of two words; all instructions of your program are stored sequentially in RAM, starting at address 0. The following instructions can be used, P representing the parameter of the instruction:

| Mnemonic | Corresponding word | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOAD P | 0 | A := RAM[P]; C += 2 |
| SAVE P | 1 | RAM[P] := A; C += 2 |
| CNST P | 2 | A := P; C += 2 |
| ADDT P | 3 | A += RAM[P]; C += 2 |
| NEGA P | 4 | A := -RAM[P]; C += 2 |
| JUMP P | 5 | C := P |
| JMPN P | 6 | If A <= 0 then C := P else C += 2. |
| HALT P | every other number | The program halts. |

At each step, the instruction at address C will be executed using the parameter stored at C + 1.
Both A and C will be initialized to 0 at the start of a program's execution. The word at -1 is supposed to be your input which can be guaranteed to be non-negative, other words not storing any instructions initially contain 0. The number stored at -2 will be considered your program's output, which must also be positive in all but finitely many cases.

### Rules

At the initial state, your program may not occupy more than the first 2048 words, however, during execution, there are no bounds.
Of course, you don't have to write your program in bytecode, using some assembly equivalent or ultimately any other language is fine as well, as long as you provide some rules/translator and show the result does not exceed the given bounds.

Every answer should come with some rough argument showing the program always halts, as well as some approximate lower bound on its growth rate. As the given space might very well suffice for some extremely fast-growing functions, it might be helpful to utilize the slow-/fast-growing hierarchy, as it provides a relatively simple way to compare two answers. Answers will be ranked by lower bounds that can be shown to hold.

#### Questions

I wonder what tags could be used in this case, atomic-code-golf, restricted-source and busy-beaver perhaps? Not entirely sure whether these fit. Also, is there any behavior left undefined? It doesn't seem like that's the case, but there might be some edge cases I forgot about.

Comment: 2048 words should be enough to run every possible program

Comment: @l4m2 what do you mean by that? you surely can't just take the first <input> programs and run them, otherwise you'd have to solve the halting problem

Comment: I mean there's, in any measure, way to make it better, in the 2048, and we don't want a "who say bigger number" game

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, so you'd reduce the maximum size, correct?

Comment: no, reducing to turing incomplete likely make it too weak

Comment: @l4m2 not the RAM size, the allowed code length

Comment: since this has been posted, it suggest shortening to one line and deleting to save sandbox space.

Answer (score 0):

[duplicate :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137880/print-a-booklet)

Comment: [Related, doesn't look to be a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216594/generate-newspaper-page-number-sets)

Comment: Frick, it's a duplicate: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137880/print-a-booklet

Answer (score 0):

## [May the wind be always at your back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224381/may-the-wind-be-always-at-your-back)

Comment: Challenge is well-written with good test cases.  My only critique is that as a puzzle, it's just "is there a path from A to B in this directed graph?"  But to get the directed graph you have to parse a bunch of ascii (well, unless you are very flexible with input), which is a "turn this ascii into a directed graph" challenge.  The former challenge would likely be a duplicate. The latter is somewhat interesting, but perhaps a bit mechanical.  I find it helpful to look at challenges from this "what is the _heart_ of this problem?" perspective.

Comment: Note: The above isn't to say you shouldn't post the challenge -- it's definitely postable quality. Just giving you some feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, though I'm not sure how to improve this (the only thing I can think of is to make the challenge be "list all of the possible paths"). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could make it "turn this ascii into an adjacency list or matrix," which is more focused, but  becomes too technical.  My comment is probably more useful for evaluating future ideas rather than as a way to improve this one.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest adding in a falsey testcase where the wind deposits you on a patch of calm sea next to Ithica, similar to the west path in the third test case

Comment: Thanks, implemented

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## Compute a real root of a cubic polynomial.

You are given a cubic polynomial of the form \$x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c\$ and your task is to compute one real root of this polynomial, or equivalently a solution to the equation \$x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c = 0\$.

Input will be three numbers \$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$. These are guaranteed to be real numbers. The inputs may be taken separately or as a list or a vector or whatever else is convenient in your language.

A cubic polynomial always has at least one real root, and can have up to three. It always has three complex roots but the non real ones are of no interest for this challenge. If the polynomial has multiple real roots, outputting any one of them is fine.

Output should be one number. Solutions with three correct decimal places are good enough, more accuracy or exact algebraic expressions are fine too.

This can be solved by using [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) but this requires handling of complex roots and some messy lengthy algebra. Alternatively one could use some algorithm for a numeric approximation such as [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). If your language has a build-in that works as well as long as you fish out exactly one real root.

Test cases can be easily generated with any online solver for cubic equations such as [this one](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/cubicequation.php).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and thank you for using the Sandbox! I've edited the MathJax slightly (we use `\$` as delimiters here), and added in a couple more edits to fit the site defaults slightly better. Feel free to revert these if you dislike them. I'd suggest including some test cases in the challenge body as challenges should be self-contained, and linking to the generator for even more. Finally, for tags, I'd suggest [code-golf], [polynomials], [math] and [number-theory]

Answer (score 0):

Your client asks you to produce an "org chart" of their statically generated Website's navigation paths.

You can use the [Google sheets chart feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9146871?hl=en) if you like, as long as the chart looks similar to what the client expects here:

[image]

Notice that a child can only have one parent, so you need to calculate the shortest path to the root element (aka "Home").

Your coding challenge is to create the same chart programatically for the
[static html](https://s.natalian.org/2021-04-26/site.zip) as well as their Website at https://simple.goserverless.sg/

Example output:

```
generate-site-structure [index.html | https://simple.goserverless.sg/]
Bread,Products
Jam,Products
Products,Home
Privacy Policy,About Us
Sustainability statement,About Us
About Us,Home
```

Comment: Welcome to the Sandbox! This currently isn't nearly clear enough, I'd recommend looking at some other [tag:graphical-output] challenges to see the typical requirements. You also haven't specified an objective winning criterion; the most popular by far is [tag:code-golf] (shortest code), but there are also some others like [tag:fastest-algorithm] or [tag:test-battery].

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to be clearer by stating what the expected output is to be. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal. Are programs supposed to print that exact text, or a graphical representation of it, or take some sort of site as input and make a representation of it?

Comment: The output is the text/csv which can be drawn by Google Sheets as a organizational chart.

Comment: That definitely needs to be much clearer in the post. Without much prior knowledge or assumptions, it should be possible to tell exactly what is expected of answers from the challenge text, and also typically with a bit of explanation on how and some test cases. I'd recommend answering a challenge or two, doing that gives you a pretty good idea of what a challenge needs in order to be clear enough to answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Draft] 2x2 algorithm with half the faces

A fun fact about the 2x2x2 Rubik's cube is that due to the way a 2x2 only has two layers, doing one turn on one face is indistinguishable from doing the same direction turn on the opposite face and then rotating the cube. So algorithms, that is sequences of moves and cube rotations, ignoring the cube's orientation in space, only need to turn the up (U), right (R), and front (F) faces, and don't need to turn the down (D), left (L), and back (B) faces.

A move is represented by a face, one of the letters `U`, `R`, `F`, followed by a direction: clockwise (empty string or space  ), counterclockwise (apostrophe `'`), or 180 degrees (`2`). A cube rotation is represented as one of `x` (rotating the entire cube wrt R face), `y` (rotating the entire cube wrt U face), and `z` (rotating the entire cube wrt F face).

[image]
(credit: J Perm)

[image]
(credit: Ibero Rubik)

From the previous example, `U` move is equivalent to `D y`, meaning the result of turning the top face clockwise is indistinguishable from the result of turning the bottom face clockwise and then rotating the entire cube clockwise wrt the top face.

It is possible to rewrite algorithms with cube rotations into algorithms without cube rotations by appropriate substitution of all following face rotations. For example, `y F` is equivalent to `R`, and `y U` is equivalent to `U`.

Your task is given an input 2x2 algorithm, rewrite it using only U, R, and F moves, and without cube rotations.

---

I know this notation is probably confusing to people not familiar with it, so let me know how I can clarify the post.

Answer (score 0):

### The Smallest Grammar Problem

---

Here is a write-up for the main site.

**Some changes I want to add are:**

1. You can use any language.
2. You must formally prove the Big-O of the worst case of your algorithm in your answer.
3. You must formally prove the correctness of your algorithm as well.

As far as running the code, that's up to the viewers of the page who wish to run the algorithm, as I can't reasonably be expected to compile code from so many different languages.

4. Before I post to main, I will have a solution to the problem which provides correct answers and can check if an output of your algorithm is correct.  It will be coded in Python 3.x.  But since the question is about fastest algorithm, that shouldn't matter.
5. Your algorithm only needs to provide one correct smallest grammar to a given input string (there are usually many), and it must be in standard form (see below).
6. Therefore my Python 3.x code will enumerate all smallest grammars up to standard form.
7. I will provide an example formal proof of my algorithm, both so that you can see what a formal proof entails and also so that we know that the solutions we're computing are indeed correct.

How does this all sound to you all?  Where would you like to see improvements in the write-up?  I am okay  with rewriting the whole thing :)

---

The [Smallest Grammar Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem) (SGP), is defined as:

> Given an input string s, compute a smallest CFG g such that L(g) = {s} generates the string and only the string s itself.  Grammar size is defined as:

$$
|g| = \sum_{A \in \text{Vars}(g)} |g(A)|
$$

Where the grammar is $$g = \{ A \to g(A), B \to g(B), C \to g(C), \dots \}, \\ \text{ and, } |g(A)|$$ simply takes the string length.

So the size of the grammar g is the sum of the lengths of all right hand sides (RHS's) of the production rules making up g.

All literature on this problem talks about approximation algorithms, and not one article demonstrates a decent *exact* smallest grammar algorithm.  That is to say,  computing the very thing the article is about in the first place.  I would personally like to see what an exact SGP algorithm looks like.  How optimal can we make it, and so on...

I have had many ideas on how to solve the problem.  Every one of my attempts ended up with inefficient (exponential running time code).  The question is can you make a speedy SGP algorithm.

The language of choice for speed of development is of course Python.  Though these resulting programs should not be used in a production compressor for large data.  Still, an exponential algoritm remains inefficient even if ported to C++.

So, the benchmark will be running time.  You are to use standard Python 3.x, and not Cython, etc.

I have included below some relatively bug-free boilerplate utility code that you may wish to use.  It handles the methods for enumerating substrings of a grammar and so on.

These are methods I will use in my own answer, which I am currently still designing.  My approach will use what I call the "Groupoid of smallest grammars".   Groupoids are heavily involved in combinatorial optimization problems at an advanced level, so from that heuristic they seem like the right structure to use.  Another way to code this problem is translating it into a linear integer programming problem and representing substring conflicts using summation modulo 2 (or something like that).  Though, linear programming problems open another can of worms since a lot of those problems also have hard running times.

---

To teach you about the problem, let's inspect some examples.  Though we cannot prove that the examples are indeed smallest grammars - there are no theorems out there that tell whether a certain grammar is indeed minimal.  A proven algorithm however, tells you whether or not your grammar is minimal.  You will need to provide a proof of your algorithm in English / math text accompanied by relavent chunks of your algorithm.

---

**Example 1.**  Take the string s = aaaa.  Reduce it with B -> aa to get the CFG g = { A -> BB, B -> aa}$.  Measure its size:  |g| = 4 which is the same size as s and so therefore no compression happened.

**Example 2.** Take the string s = aaaaaa.  Reduce using either B -> aaa,  or C -> aa to get two smallest grammars:

$$
g = \{A \to BB, B \to aaa\} \\
g' = \{A \to CCC, C \to aa\}
$$

Those, by experience and inspection, are precisely the full set of smallest grammars of the string of 6 $a$'s.

**Example 3.** Let s = abababab.  Reduce using first B -> bab then C -> ab.

You get:

$$
g = \{A \to aBaB, B \to bab \}, |g| = 7 \\
g' = \{A \to CCCC, C \to ab \}, |g| = 6 \\
$$

So as you can see, a naive greedy algorithm can quite easily make wrong min / max guesses and come up with a resulting grammar that is not optimal.

Define a grammar to be *reduced* if no substring of length 2 or more occuring within it occurs more than once.

Reduced does not imply smallest and smallest does not imply reduced.  However, every smallest grammar can be reduced, without a change to its size.  Thus we will call a reduced smallest grammar the *standard form* of the smallest grammar.

---

### Rules

<strike>1. Your algorithm must not only solve the SGP (which is to compute at least one smallest grammar), but it must enumerate all smallest grammars, in standard form, of a given input string.</strike>

2. You must provide a formal proof of your algoritm in your answer.  I.e. a mathematical argument that it does indeed compute the output describe in rule 1.

<strike>3. Python 3.x, no Cython or C++.</strike>

The standard form requirement reduces the total number of result smallest grammars that you must list.

### Code to get you started:

```
# pip install bidict

from bidict import bidict
# Any involved grammar in a smallest grammar algorithm will usually have unique RHS's and unique
# variables on the left.  So it's a perfect use case for a bidirectional dictionary.  Using
# one should speed up the code greatly, otherwise we have to loop through dict values or create
# an inverse dictionary on the fly.

class Grammar:
    def __init__(self, s:str):
        """
        Start out with the trivial grammar g = {S -> s}.
        """        
        self._alphabet = set(s)
        self._previousVar = 'A'
        A = self.new_variable()
        self._start = A
        self._definition = bidict({ A : s })   # Bidict is useful, we do use the inverse lookup
        
    def grammar_size(self):
        """
        This is the standard definition of grammar size (cost) used in all literature
        with regards to the smallest grammar problem.  Minimizing this means you've found
        a smallest grammar for the given input string s.
        """
        size = 0
        for A, rhs in self._definition.items():
            size += len(rhs)
        return size
    
    def __getitem__(self, A):
        """
        Compute one iteration of expansion at a variable only.
        """
        return self._definition[A]
    
    def fully_expanded_string(self, s=None, memo=None):
        """
        Fully expand the a string passed in.  Could be a variable or a string of mixed
        variables and terminals.  Any string really.  If variables of this grammar
        occur within the string, they are fully expanded to what the grammar defines
        them to be expanded to, recursively.
        """
        if memo is None:
            memo = {}
        if s is None:
            s = self._start
        exp = ''
        for x in self._definition[s]:
            if x in self._definition:
                exp += self.fully_expanded_string(x)
            else:
                exp += x
        memo[s] = exp
        return exp        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        """
        The obvious representation for debugging / showing results.
        """
        rep = ''
        for A, rhs in self._definition.items():
            rep += A + ' ---> ' + rhs + '\n'
        rep = rep[:-1]  # remove last newline
        return rep
        
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)
        
    def new_variable(self):
        """
        Take the first unicode character that is not already in the grammar's alphabet.
        So it will eventually take weird-appearing characters, but who cares.  I think this
        methodology beats escape or delimit characters.  However, you're also limited to a 
        maximal alphabet size that is the Unicode character set.  That's usually just fine.
        If not, then what on Earth are you compressing ? :)
        """        
        X = self._previousVar
        while X in self._alphabet:
            X = chr(ord(X) + 1)            
        self._alphabet.add(X)
        self._previousVar = X
        return X
    
    def greedily_reduce(self):
        """
        A grammar is defined to be reduced if no substring of length >= 2 occurs twice, anywhere
        within the grammar.  There are many paths to a reduced grammar.  The smallest grammar
        problem involves taking the correct reduction path such that the resulting grammar is
        indeed minimal in size.  Greedy algorithms are known not to work in general for producing
        a smallest grammar.  However, they can easily produce a reduced grammar as you can witness.
        A smallest grammar is not necessarily reduced, though there exists a smallest grammar which
        is the reduction of that smallest grammar.  Reducing a smallest grammar would involve
        compressing all substrings of length 2 that occur exactly twice. g = {S -> abab} has the 
        same size as g' = {S -> AA, A -> ab}, namely 4.  Thus reducing a smallest grammar does not
        reduce the size (obviously), but instead puts it into a "standard form", which might be
        useful to your algorithm.
        """
        R = self.repeating_disjoint_substring_indices()                
        while len(R) > 0:
            m = self.arbitrary_greedy_max_function(R)                        
            
            if m not in self._definition.inv:
                M = self.new_variable()
            else:
                M = self._definition.inv[m]
                
            for A, indices in R[m].items():
                subtract = 0
                for i in indices:
                    rhs = self._definition[A]
                    self._definition[A] = rhs[0:i-subtract] + M + rhs[i+len(m)-subtract:] 
                    subtract += len(m) - 1                         
            self._definition[M] = m
            R = self.repeating_disjoint_substring_indices()
            
    def arbitrary_greedy_max_function(self, R:dict):
        """
        Seems like a good choice.  The total coverage of a substring if you were to compress it
        into a grammar rule.
        For example:
              If g = {A -> BaBaBaCC, B -> CCC, C -> aaa} then (3 Ba's) * |Ba| = 3 * 2 = 6 is maximal.
        """        
        total_indices = lambda rule_indices: sum(len(x) for x in rule_indices.values())
        return max(R.keys(), key=lambda x: len(x) * total_indices(R[x]))        
            
    
    def repeating_disjoint_substring_indices(self, min_len=2):
        """
        If there is overlap, this algorithm clearly does a leftmost packing.
        Same as `disjoint_substring_indices()` except we compute only the
        substrings that occur >= 2 times within the same rule or in two
        separate rules.
        
        Output form:
        {
           'substring1' : {
                 'A': [0, 3, 7],
                 'B': [1, 4, 8],
            },
           'substring2' :  ...
        }        
        where 'A' indicates the rule in which the indices occur, and the list is the list
        of indices within the rule RHS string where you'll find the substring occuring.
        The indices returned are such that the substrings occuring at those indices are mutually
        disjoint (they don't overlap).
        """        
        return self._repeatingSubstringIndices(min_len, lambda t, indices: indices)
    
    def repeating_substring_indices_all(self, min_len=2):
        """
        Return all substring indices even if there is overlaps among them.
        Output form:
        {
           'substring1' : {
                 'A': [0, 3, 7],
                 'B': [1, 4, 8],
            },
           'substring2' :  ...
        }        
        where 'A' indicates the rule in which the indices occur, and the list is the list
        of indices within the rule RHS string where you'll find the substring occuring.
        This includes all occurences even if two occurences overlap.
        """        
        return self._repeatingSubstringIndices(min_len, lambda t, indices: self.all_substring_indices(t))
    
    def _repeatingSubstringIndices(self, min_len=2, rule_indices_func=None): 
        """
        Output form:
        {
           'substring1' : {
                 'A': [0, 3, 7],
                 'B': [1, 4, 8],
            },
           'substring2' :  ...
        }        
        where 'A' indicates the rule in which the indices occur, and the list is the list
        of indices within the rule RHS string where you'll find the substring occuring.  Overlap
        or disjoint is governed by the rule_indices_func passed in.
        """
        S = {}        
        for A, rhs in self._definition.items():
            T = self.disjoint_substring_indices(rhs, min_len)
            for t, indices in T.items():                
                if t not in S:
                    S[t] = { A : indices }
                else:
                    S[t][A] = indices
        R = {}        
        for t, rule_indices in S.items():
            if len(rule_indices) >= 2:
                R[t] = rule_indices_func(t, rule_indices)
            else:
                for var, indices in rule_indices.items():
                    if len(indices) >= 2:
                        R[t] = rule_indices_func(t, rule_indices)
                        break
        return R
    
    @staticmethod
    def disjoint_substring_indices(s:str, min_len=2, max_len=None):
        """
        Leftmost-first packed indices of all substrings of the string s.  The substring
        occurences (indexes) are guaranteed to be of disjointly occuring substrings.
        If two occurences overlap, by for-loop logic we're taking the leftmost.  Hence
        "leftmost-first packed".
        Output form:
        {
           'substring1' : {
                 'A': [0, 3, 7],
                 'B': [1, 4, 8],
            },
           'substring2' :  ...
        }        
        where 'A' indicates the rule in which the indices occur, and the list is the list
        of indices within the rule RHS string where you'll find the substring occuring.
        The indices are such that the substrings occuring at those indices are disjoint 
        (they don't overlap).
        """
        if max_len is None:
            max_len = int(len(s)/2)   # Maximum length of a repeated substring
        S = {}
        for i in range(0, len(s)-min_len+1):
            for j in range(i+min_len, i+min(max_len, len(s))+1):
                t = s[i:j]
                if t in S:
                    if i >= max(S[t]) + len(t):
                        S[t].append(i)
                else:
                    S[t] = [i]
        return S
                
    def all_substring_indices(self, t:str):
        """
        The indices of all occurences of the given substring.  Output form:
        {
           'A' : [0, 3, 7],
           'B' : [1, 4, 8],
           ...
        }
        where 'A' indicates the rule in which the indices occur, and the list is the list
        of indices within the rule RHS string where you'll find the substring occuring.
        This includes all occurences even if two occurences overlap.
        """
        R = {}        
        for A, rhs in self._definition.items():
            for i in range(0, len(rhs)-len(t)):
                if rhs[i:].startswith(t):
                    if A not in R:
                        R[A] = [i]
                    else:
                        R[A].append(i)
        return R
    
    def include_all_possible_rules(self):
        """
        A possible rule is one such that the length of its RHS is >= 2 and fully
        expanded it occurs at least twice in the input string s.  Including all possible
        rules does not change the fact that the grammar expands to s for some starting
        variable.  In other words we still have a grammar for s, by definition, though
        some of its rules may be unused.
        """
        # So first get all disjointly repeating substrings:
        R = self.repeating_disjoint_substring_indices()
        # To "include all rules" we form a rule for each repeating substring:
        
        for r in R:
            A = self.new_variable()
            if r not in self._definition.inv:
                self._definition[A] = r
                
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'aaaaaa'
    g = Grammar(s)
    g.greedily_reduce()
    print(g)
    print('The canonical example on a singleton alphabet.  The smallest example such that the smallest '
          f'grammar is indeed smaller than the input {s}')
    print('-----------')
    s = 'ababab'
    g = Grammar(s)
    g.greedily_reduce()
    print(g)
    print(f"This is known to indeed be a smallest grammar of {s}, by inspection.")    
    print('-----------')
    s = 'abcabcabababc'
    g = Grammar(s)
    g.greedily_reduce()
    print(g)
    print(f"Similarly, this too also is probably a smallest grammar for {s}")
    print('-----------')
    s = 'ababababbaaaaaaaabbbbaa'
    print(s)
    g = Grammar(s)
    g.include_all_possible_rules()
    g.greedily_reduce()
    s1 = g.fully_expanded_string()
    print(g)
    assert (s1 == s)
    print('A more complicated example demonstrating "including all possible rules" and then greedily reducing '
          'everything.')
    print('-----------')
```

### Which prints:

```
A ---> BBB
B ---> aa
The canonical example on a singleton alphabet.  The smallest example such that the smallest grammar is indeed smaller than the input aaaaaa
-----------
A ---> BBB
B ---> ab
This is known to indeed be a smallest grammar of ababab, by inspection.
-----------
A ---> CCBBC
B ---> ab
C ---> Bc
Similarly, this too also is probably a smallest grammar for abcabcabababc
-----------
ababababbaaaaaaaabbbbaa
A ---> DDOLLLbbbO
B ---> ab
C ---> aba
D ---> BB
E ---> ba
F ---> bab
G ---> abb
H ---> bb
I ---> bba
J ---> bbL
K ---> baa
L ---> aa
M ---> aaa
N ---> LL
O ---> bL
A more complicated example demonstrating "including all possible rules" and then greedily reducing everything.
-----------
```

Comment: The explanation is kind of long, and I would suggest separating a section that clarifies the task and input-output format.

Answer (score 0):

## Cleaning KoTH

Clean up a 50x75 room with a JSbot before there is too much junk!

### The Challenge

A 50x75 room is cluttered 375 items, each taking up 1 cell of space. Create a JSbot that takes an array as an input to clean up the room. If the bot is on a cell with junk in it, the junk is automatically removed.

Each bot will be paired against another bot. One bot will be the "cleaner," the other will be a "disorganizer." The cleaner is exactly what it is. The disorganizer, every turn, has a 10% chance of being able to place a junk where it is.

The disorganizer wins if the amount of junk reaches 400 or more, while the cleaner wins if the amount of junk reaches 0.

### Rules

- Preset commands you may use are:

  - `left(bot_name)` Moves left 1 cell (x-1)
  - `right(bot_name)` Moves right 1 cell (x+1)
  - `up(bot_name)` Moves up 1 cell (y+1)
  - `down(bot_name)` Moves down 1 cell (y-1)
- Storing data in your bot is allowed!
- 

### Example

Here is an example of a bot, and how to format it.

```
bots.ConfusedBot = { // bots.Foo where Foo is the name of your bot
    x: 0 // 0 is the center
    y: 0 // 0 is the center
    clean: function (array) { // cleaning function
        left("ConfusedBot");
        right("ConfusedBot");
        up("ConfusedBot");
        down("ConfusedBot");
    }
    sabotage: function (array) { // disorganizing funcction
        up("ConfusedBot");
        down("ConfusedBot");
        left("ConfusedBot");
        right("ConfusedBot");
    }
}
```

Comments and/or concerns? Comment down below to notify me.

Comment: I'd recommend giving [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/king-of-the-hill/info) a read. KotHs are one of the hardest types of challenges to get right (if not _the_ hardest). Currently it doesn't look like there's much strategy at all here.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yep, that's been a problem for all of these. I will edit it to make it more strategic.

Answer (score 0):

Given a subset of {+,*,<,=,E,A,(constant),(variable)}. For most of the subsets, use the symbols to express [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis).

Output format flexible. Most subset, and on tie, smallest (code length+sum symbols used) in each language wins. (So there'll also be a winner in Text)

You can also choose to focus on sum symbols used, and claim that you answered in Custom, counting like a 0-byte solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Regex, ASCII-literal

### Objective

Execute the given regex for the given text. The regex is in a special scheme I made.

### Motivation

For most regexes the usual languages support, they assign some printable ASCII characters for special instructions. For POSIX as an example, `*` is the Kleene star, `.` matches an arbitrary character, and `(` and `)` groups a subexpression. Because of this, If such characters themselves were to be matched, I must escape them by a backslash `\`. This may cause the regex seem obfuscated. Not to mention that in most languages, backslashes must be escaped themselves like `\\`.

So instead of printable ASCII characters, I chose ASCII control characters to assign some special instructions.

### Inputs

Two strings indicating the **regex** and the **text**. They are assumed to consist of ASCII characters. Otherwise, the entire challenge falls in *don't care* situation.

### Output

A list of pairs of integers. Each pair indicates the starting position and the ending position of each strings matched.

Indexing is implementation-defined, but preferred to be zero-indexed.

Each pair shall be left-inclusive of its indicated string. The right, however, is implementation-defined whether inclusive or exclusive. (Exclusive is preferred)

### Regex

Here, I shall call a unit of regex a **packet**.

For all characters within `\x20`–`\x7E`, it is a minimal packet that matches itself.

For control characters (with some exceptions), however, it has a special functionality. It classifies to one of:

- A minimal packet.
- A **parenthesis**. A pair of parentheses group packets into one packet.
- A **unary operator**. They accept one packet, and they all are suffixes. They have higher precedence to all binary operators.
- A **binary operator**. They accept two packets, they all are infixes, and they all associate to right.

The regex munches each strings matched. In other words, the matched strings cannot overlap.

If an empty string is matched, it shall be ignored. In other words, all matched strings shall be nonempty.

The regex is case-sensitive by default.

### Text

The **lines** of the text are delimited by `\n`, `\f`, `\r`, and `\v`.

The **words** of the text are separated by ASCII whitespaces (  and `\t`, in addition to the above).

### Control characters

- `\x00` (**NUL**; Null) has an implementation-defined functionality. It's because in some languages, strings are null-terminated.
- `\x01` (**SOH**; Start of Header): Minimal packet. It matches the start of a line.
- `\x02` (**STX**; Start of Text): Left parenthesis corresponding to ETX.
- `\x03` (**ETX**; End of Text): Right parenthesis corresponding to STX. Concatenates the packets inside.
- `\x04` (**EOT**; End of Transmission): Minimal packet. It matches the end of a line.
- `\x05` (**ENQ**; Enquiry): Left parenthesis corresponding to ACK or NAK.
- `\x06` (**ACK**; Acknowledgement): Right parenthesis corresponding to ENQ. It serves as an arbitrary-input OR gate. The first alternative that matches shall be matched.
- `\x07` (**BEL**; Bell): Unary operator. It "inverts" its operand, like this:

  - If its operand is a minimal packet that matches a single character, it matches a character the packet **doesn't** match.
  - It commutes with a unary operator.
  - It distributes to a binary operator.
  - It distributes to packets within parentheses.
  - Otherwise, it has no effect.
- `\x08` (**BS**; Backspace): Minimal packet. It matches an arbitrary ASCII whitespace.
- `\x09` (**HT**; Horizontal Tab): Minimal packet. It matches `\t`.
- `\x0A` (**LF**; Line Feed): Minimal packet. It matches `\n`.
- `\x0B` (**VT**; Vertical Tab): Minimal packet. It matches `\v`.
- `\x0C` (**FF**; Form Feed): Minimal packet. It matches `\f`.
- `\x0D` (**CR**; Carriage Return): Minimal packet. It matches `\r`.
- `\x0E` (**SO**; Shift Out): Minimal packet. It matches an arbitrary lowercase Latin letter.
- `\x0F` (**SI**; Shift In): Minimal packet. It matches an arbitrary uppercase Latin letter.
- `\x10` (**DLE**; Data Link Escape): Unary operator. Its operand shall be matched case-insensitive.
- `\x11` (**DC1**; Device Control One): Unary operator. Its operand shall be matched zero or more times. It is greedy.
- `\x12` (**DC2**; Device Control Two): Unary operator. Its operand shall be matched one or more times. It is greedy.
- `\x13` (**DC3**; Device Control Three): Unary operator. Its operand shall be matched two or more times. It is greedy.
- `\x14` (**DC4**; Device Control Four): Unary operator. Its operand shall be matched zero or one time. It is greedy.
- `\x15` (**NAK**; Negative Acknowledgement): Right parenthesis corresponding to ENQ. It is equivalent to ACK BEL.
- `\x16` (**SYN**; Synchronous Idle): Binary operator. If and only if the operands match the same string, it shall match the string. Has higher precedence to CAN, and has lower precedence to EM.
- `\x17` (**ETB**; End of Transmission Block): Minimal packet. Matches either the start of a word or the end of a word.
- `\x18` (**CAN**; Cancel): Binary operator. Two-packets version of ENQ-ACK. Has the lowest precedence.
- `\x19` (**EM**; End of Medium): Binary operator. Treats surrounding characters as escaped, and matches a character within the range they indicate, both inclusive. If the left operand has higher ASCII code point than the right operand, the range wraps around the ASCII codepage.
- `\x1A` (**SUB**; Substitute): Minimal packet. Matches an arbitrary character.
- `\x1B` (**ESC**; Escape): As a **prefix**, this character is used to escape a control character. An escaped ASCII character, including DEL (but not necessarily including NUL), shall match itself.
- `\x1C` (**FS**; File Separator): Minimal packet. Matches a hexadecimal digit, case-insensitive.
- `\x1D` (**GS**; Group Separator): Minimal packet. Matches a decimal digit.
- `\x1E` (**RS**; Record Separator): Minimal packet. Matches an octal digit.
- `\x1F` (**US**; Unit Separator): Minimal packet. Matches a binary digit.
- `\x7F` (**DEL**; Delete): Unless escaped by ESC, this character shall be skipped. It doesn't even count as a packet.

### Errors

Upon the following conditions, it shall fall in an implementation-defined behavior to indicate an error:

- Unpaired parenthesis
- Unary/Binary operator without an operand

### Examples

(WIP)

### Ungolfed solution

#### Haskell

(WIP)

## Sandbox questions

- Is this challenge too hard or cumbersome?
- Do you have better ideas for the functionalities of control characters?

Comment: Suggest map to usual RegEx, and explanation for those whthout direct map

Answer (score 0):

## Base Guard (Rewritten)

[base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

[Base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224730/base-ically-god): part 1

This is part 2, Strongly suggest you go try out the first one if you haven't tried it.

### Story

As one of the solvers, You've managed to get to the door of the base heaven. In front of the door stands the base guard @Lyxal, he was angry that you all just left the encoded text on the ground, he deems you to clean(decode) the ground before joining the party, those who are irresponsible gets no ticket!

### Task

You will get 2 inputs

- First being `X` which is a non-negative integer in base of base list.
- Second being base which is a list of bases.
- bases range from 1 ~ 10
- The base will contain at least one not `1` base
- answer should be in the base 10

Example:

```
X, [bases] -> answer
110 ,[2] -> 6
30 ,[2,4] -> 6
2100 ,[2,3] -> 30

You may want to look at part 1 for more detail
```

## Rule

Basic Rules

Satisfy Lyxal with the shortest code, because a long code indicates that you are lazy and not doing your best!

## Sandbox

- Is this count as a dup of part 1?
- Any extra suggestions?
- Lyxal are you willing to become the guard? Or anyone else would like to be the guard?

Comment: You say lowercase alphabet, but your example uses capital F. Also, this would be a duplicate of the first part because handling higher numbers shouldn't require much modification from part 1, and indexing into the base digits is a pretty trivial extra step that doesn't add anything to the challenge anyway.

Comment: No tickets for anyone unless they impress me.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Then I will rewrite this challange to somethin more creative.

Comment: I'm good with guarding

Comment: @Lyxal **Excellent**

Answer (score 0):

### Radio station hopping

You are listening to a car radio. You are pressing seek up/down, moving you to the next frequency some radio station broadcasts on, to avoid all this pointless music and listen to all the ads, or vice versa.
But there is a tendency of these broadcasts to have your radio jump to another frequency, where signal of that radio station is stronger. So, suppose this radio station A broadcasts at 99, 100 and 101 MHz with 100 MHz having the strongest signal at your place. The moment you reach 101 MHz, radio will jump to 100 MHz.

Because of that, you can get trapped. Suppose there is one extra radio station B, broadcasting only at 102 MHz. The moment you are stuck at the station A, you can never listen to station B again - if you try going with frequency down, you will hit 99 and jump to 100, if you go up you reach 101 and jump to 100 again... never escaping that trap.

But if there is yet another station C at 99.5 and 98.5 MHz with latter being the strongest, you can listen to all 3 radios again - starting from B you get down to A, then down to C, then ***pressing down loops you back again to the highest frequency***.

So, you start wondering - can I listen to all radio stations at least once if I start at any frequency? And will I be able to endlessly cycle through all of them, or listen to all just once before getting cut off some stations?

**Your task:**

Get a list of radio stations, along with a designation of which has the strongest signal, in any reasonable format (1). Return one of three values to distinguish whether you can cycle through all stations indefinitely, you can cycle through all stations once or you cannot reach all stations from any starting point. Again in any reasonable format (2).

(1) Test cases have inputs as radio stations separated by semicolon, for each radio station, the strongest broadcast for the station is first, entries separated by comma. You can pick anything else as your input format, along with any reasonable extra information you would like - for example number of radio stations, number of channels each station broadcasts at etc. You can use integers (eg just multiply everything in example by 10).

(2) Test cases have output as 1 - cycle all, 2 - cycle once, 3 - cannot reach all stations. You can return anything reasonable to distinguish these three options, as long as you return/print the value. You must return, eg "you can cycle all" crashing or never stopping is NOT allowed.

**Test cases:**

input: 102; 100, 99, 101
output: 2

input: 102; 100, 99, 101; 98.5, 99.5
output: 1

input: 100, 99, 101; 103, 102, 104
output: 3

input: 100, 99, 101; 103, 102, 104; 101.5, 99.5, 103.5
output: 1

input: 100, 99; 99.5, 100.5; 102, 103; 102.5, 101.5
output: 3

May the shortest code win.

Tags: code-golf
Any suggestions? (and is this a duplicate maybe, I haven't found it but I don't know what exactly to search for here)

Answer (score 0):

## Determine tournament winners [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a table of names and per round scores, arrange the names in descending order of their [Neustadtl Sonneborn–Berger score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonneborn%E2%80%93Berger_score#Neustadtl_Sonneborn%E2%80%93Berger_score).

### Challenge

A player's Sonneborn-Berger score(which we will from now on refer to as "tiebreak score"), is the sum of the points they received in each round (\$x_{i}\$), multiplied by the points that each their round opponent achieved totally via standard scoring(\$p_{i}\$), given round count \$n\$.

Effectively, each player's score is:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n p_ix_i.
$$

Your challenge is to calculate this score for each player and arrange them in increasing order of ordinary score, and then use the tiebreak score to resolve any ties in points.

From Wikipedia:

> here is the crosstable of the 1975–80 World Correspondence Chess Championship Final (here cs indicates conventional score, ns Neustadtl score):

```
                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  cs   ns
1.  Sloth         X ½ ½ 1 ½ ½ 1 1 ½  1  ½  1  1  1  1  11   69.5
2.  Zagorovsky    ½ X 0 ½ 1 ½ 1 1 1  ½  1  1  1  1  1  11   66.75
3.  Kosenkov      ½ 1 X ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ 1  1  ½  1  1  1  1  10½  67.5
4.  Khasin        0 ½ ½ X ½ 1 ½ 0 1  1  ½  1  ½  1  ½  8½   54.75
5.  Kletsel       ½ 0 ½ ½ X ½ ½ ½ ½  0  1  1  ½  1  1  8    47.75
6.  De Carbonnel  ½ ½ ½ 0 ½ X ½ ½ 0  1  ½  ½  0  1  1  7    45.25
7.  Arnlind       0 0 ½ ½ ½ ½ X ½ 1  0  ½  ½  1  1  ½  7    42.5
8.  Dunhaupt      0 0 ½ 1 ½ ½ ½ X 0  ½  1  0  1  ½  1  7    41.5
9.  Maedler       ½ 0 0 0 ½ 1 0 1 X  1  ½  ½  ½  ½  1  7    41.5
10. Estrin        0 ½ 0 0 1 0 1 ½ 0  X  1  1  1  0  1  7    40.5
11. Walther       ½ 0 ½ ½ 0 ½ ½ 0 ½  0  X  0  1  ½  1  5½   33.25
12. Boey          0 0 0 0 0 ½ ½ 1 ½  0  1  X  ½  ½  1  5½   28.5
13. Abramov       0 0 0 ½ ½ 1 0 0 ½  0  0  ½  X  ½  1  4½   24.75
14. Siklos        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ½ ½  1  ½  ½  ½  X  1  4½   22.75
15. Nun           0 0 0 ½ 0 0 ½ 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  X  1    7.75
```

> As an example, Sloth's score is calculated as: `0.5*11 + 0.5*10.5 + 1.0*8.5 + 0.5*8.0 + 0.5*7.0 + 1.0*7.0 + 1.0*7.0 + 0.5*7.0 + 1.0*7.0 + 0.5*5.5 + 1.0*5.5 + 1.0*4.5 + 1.0*4.5 + 1.0*1.0 = 69.5`

Answer (score 0):

> Surprisingly, I don't think there has been a question about Whyte notation before. I suspect the ASCII challenge is a bit too easy, but not sure how many people are interested in a graphical challenge. Thoughts? Comments?

### Whyte notation

Write a program which turns a string containing a valid (subset of) Whyte notation into an ASCII/graphical representation.

[Whyte notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whyte_notation) is a system for succinctly describing the arrangement of wheels on a steam locomotive. For the purpose of this challenge, a valid input consists of:

- one or more wheelsets, joined by a `+` symbol
- where each wheelset is of the form `l-d1[-d2...]-t`, where:

  - `l` is an integer specifying the number of *leading wheels* (small wheels at the front of the wheelset that aren't powered, but help keep it on the tracks)
  - `d1` (and d2 etc) is the number of *driving wheels* (large wheels powered by a steam engine) coupled together. If there is more than one number, it means multiple coupled sets of driving wheels. (All the sets are powered by the same engine, but using different sets of cylinders - [divided drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_drive_(locomotive)))

(Multiple wheelsets means an [articulated locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_locomotive), that is, two engines powered by the same boiler, but able to rotate independently, which is good for getting powerful locomotives around tight bends).

For instance:

- `2-4-0` means a locomotive with 2 leading wheels (1 axle), 4 driving wheels (2 axles), and no trailing wheels. We can represent it like this: `o-O=O`
- `4-8-8-2` means a locomotive with 4 leading wheels, two coupled sets of 8 driving wheels, and 2 trailing wheels. We can represent it like this: `o-o-O=O=O=O-O=O=O=O-o`
- `2-4-2+2-4-2` means an articulated locomotive with two wheelsets. Each one consists of 2 leading wheels, 4 driving wheels and 2 trailing wheels. We can represent it like this: `o-O=O-o:o-O=O-o`

[image: A Baldwin 2-4-0 locomotive: 2 leading wheels, 4 driving wheels, no trailing wheels]

Image: A Baldwin 2-4-0 locomotive: 2 leading wheels, 4 driving wheels, no trailing wheels.

### Input

Input is a string (or equivalent) that is valid in this subset of Whyte notation. You may assume:

- Leading and trailing wheel counts are even integers in the range 0-6 inclusive.
- Driving wheel counts are even integers in the range 2-14 inclusive.
- There are 1-4 coupled sets of driving wheels per wheelset.
- There are 1-2 wheelsets.

### Output (ASCII)

The rules for output are thus:

- the train is always facing left, so the leading wheels are at the start of the input and output strings.
- leading and trailing wheels are represented as one `o` per 2 wheels, joined by `-`
- each set of driving wheels are represented as one `O` per 2 wheels, joined by `=`.
- sets of driving wheels are joined by `-`
- wheelsets are joined by `:`

### Output (graphical)

Alternatively, you may output a graphical representation of a similar type: a series of circles from left to right. At a minimum:

- all wheel circles must have a dark stroke and light fill, with the stroke no more than 10% the width of the circle
- the lowest point of all wheel circles must be equal (they all touch the same imaginary track)
- all wheel circles of a given type must be the same size
- leading/trailing wheels must have a diameter in the range 20-50% of the diameter of driving wheels
- coupled sets of driving wheels must be indicated by a horizontal line connecting their centres*.

  - `*` you may offset this line up to 40% of a driving wheel diameter in any direction to maintain artistic integrity
- non-coupled wheels must not be connected, and have a space in the range 25-50% of the diameter of a driving wheel between them.
- for an articulated locomotive, the two wheelsets must be separated by a space of between 100% and 150% of a driving wheel diameter.

### Scoring

This is code golf, shortest program in bytes wins. Standard rules/loopholes apply. There are two categories: ASCII output and graphical output.

Comment: Make it one or the other, otherwise it's too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code golf too simple? Do I need to add more? Has something similar been done before?

The idea of this golf is to convert a string of 3 or more characters to a grammatically correct list.

Examples:

`12345` becomes `1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.`

`ab5` becomes `a, b, and 5.`

A comma and space is to be inserted between each character, and the last character should be preceded by "and", and be followed by a period. Your code should be able to handle up to 50 characters in series.

Comment: Well, you need to flesh out your challenge a little more. I'd suggest putting the last paragraph at the top and adding more test cases. However, I don't know how interesting this would be.

Comment: May input contains whitespace characters and / or comma?

Answer (score 0):

## How Many Students are in our clubs?

You are a principal in CG High School, and you want your school fliers to include data on how many students are part of any particular set of clubs. You command your secretary to get this data, but they goofed up.

Instead of giving you the data on how many students attend (for example) tech club, math club, and spanish club as their only clubs, they included students who attend more clubs, like the arts club! You decide to fix the data yourself.

## Challenge

Your school has n clubs, and for each subset of the n clubs, you have data on how many students attend the clubs in that subset (but potentially more clubs).

In this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, you want to output data for each subset which tells you how many students attend exactly those clubs in that subset (and no others).

## Input/Output

We represent each subset as an n digit binary number by placing a 1 in the ith position if the ith club is in the subset. For example, the number 3, in binary, is 11, meaning that it represents the subset of the first and second clubs.

The input (zero-indexed) list is of length 2^n, with the secretary's data for a particular subset placed at the index representing that subset (as in the previous paragraph).

The output is also a list of length 2^n, with the data changed.

**Input:**

- List of length 2^n of non-negative integers
- (Optional) positive integer n

**Output:**

- List of length 2^n of non-negative integers

## Test Cases

```
[41,16,15,14,5,5,6,2] -> [10,8,6,5,3,3,4,2]
```

More to be added

## Sandbox

I worded this challenge really poorly: any help on explaining this better?

Answer (score 0):

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225604/lets-play-judgement)

Comment: I think the explanation for how the game works could be a bit clearer. How many cards are dealt each round? How is the trump card chosen?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Draft] Write out the 2x2 Hamiltonian Circuit

Unlike the 3x3 Rubik's Cube, which famously has over 43 quintillion possible positions, the 2x2 Pocket Cube "only" has about 3.7 million positions, making a Hamiltonian circuit (a set of moves that visits every position exactly once) perfectly feasible to output or store in its entirety.

The full circuit was posted by cuBerBruce in 2011 on the [SpeedSolving Forums](https://www.speedsolving.com/threads/hamiltonian-circuit-for-the-entire-2x2x2-cube-group.34318/). You don't need to understand any Rubik's cube notation to complete this challenge. You only need to understand simple string replacements (in the form of a context-free grammar), in that lower case letters are "non-terminal" and can be replaced with longer strings, while upper case letters are "terminal", in that they are "atomic" and cannot be replaced further. For example, given `b=URURUR` and `a=bURUR`, you can replace the `b` in `a` to get `a=URURURURUR`, and you cannot expand `a` any further.

One additional detail: if a letter is followed by an apostrophe, you replace the letter and the apostrophe in the string with the *inverse* of the moves. That means the the entire string is reversed and the direction of all moves is reversed: `U` becomes `V` and vice versa, `R` <-> `S`, and `F` <-> `G`. More formally, `(ab)'=b'a'`, so for example `a'=(bURUR)'=R'U'R'U'b'=SVSV(URURUR)'=SVSVSVSVSV`.

Todo: upload full move list and compute hash

---

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: Should you maybe allow to choose whatever tokens you want instead of `U,V,R,S,F,G`, as long as there's only a single valid way to parse it to the tokens?

Comment: @CommandMaster this question is a kolmogorov-complexity question, about producing a constant string, and I intend all solutions to be able to be verified by hash

Answer (score 0):

You want to have some drinks. Each bottle of drink has a drink itself and \$n\$ other parts (the bottle, etc.) \$P_1, P_2, ..., P_n\$.  Thus when buying a bottle of drink, you also get one of each of \$P_1, P_2, ..., P_n\$.

You can buy a bottle of drink using 1 dollar, \$a_1 P_1\$s, \$a_2 P_2\$s, ..., or \$a_n P_n\$s.

Given the amount of dollars \$b\$ and amount of each part you have \$c_1, c_2, ..., c_n\$<sup>[1]</sup>, how many bottles of drink can you have?

You may choose to borrow some parts, aka. having a negative amount of some parts during the buying and drinking, so long as after the whole process you don'thave negative amount. But beware that simply giving each part a value and use the actual worth of the drink itself may fail. See example (*) below.

Also, you need to handle Infinity results correctly. I'd accept format `Infinity`, `∞`, `1/0`, for other formats ask here or on meta for a default.

Test cases:

```
n, a, b, c => resuly
1, [2], 5, [0] => 10 // Borrow 10 P1, buy 10BoD, and return
1, [2], 0, [10] => 10
2, [3,4], 1, [0,0] => 1 // (*)
2, [3,3], 1, [0,0] => 3 // (**)
2, [2,2], 0, [0,0] => Infinity
2, [1,2], 0, [0,1] => Infinity
```

(*) If you get 2, you result in 2 \$P_1\$s and 2 \$P_2\$s, neither of which afford one BoD and therefore you can't pay.

However, if you just claim that each \$P_1\$ worth $0.333 and each \$P_2\$ worth $0.250, then the drink itself worth $0.417, and you can drink two of them, which is incorrect.

(**) Even though you can't get 2 as that gives you 2 \$P_1\$s and 2 \$P_2\$s, which is not enough to pay; getting 3 gives you 3 \$P_1\$s and 3 \$P_2\$s, and with the initially $1 you can pay the fee of 3 bottles of drink.

One sentence meaning:

Given \$n, \{a_i\}, b, \{c_i\}, i=1..n\$, find the largest integer \$r\$, maybe infinite, such that \$b+\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{c_i+r}{a_i}\right\rfloor\ge r\$.

Input range:

- \$n>0, a_i>0, b, c_i\ge 0\$

## Sandbox Notes

- Should I take `c` input or just assume it's zero at [1]?

Comment: I mostly get the problem statement from the first three paragraphs, but the rest of the challenge sort of loses me.  I can piece together a bit from the test cases.  If you added a more worked through example perhaps I could help rephrase the parts of the challenge I don't get right now.

Comment: @WheatWizard Is treating borrowing as having negative amount of parts or pay after drinking better? Also fixed a bug in test cases. And do [such question](https://www.nowcoder.com/questionTerminal/3480a033b60845dc99e6c4361bc931a6) have an English usualseen version?

Answer (score 0):

## Implement the ordering monoid

### Objective

Mimic Haskell's `(<>) :: Ordering -> Ordering -> Ordering`.

### What's the fuss?

This particular monoid is rather useful for comparing sequential containers lexicographically.

### Format

Though `Ordering` is defined as a three-element enumeration, in this challenge, the format of the 2 inputs and the output is arbitrary.

The 2 inputs and the output must be the same domain, and their classification of their values (see below) also must be the same. This restriction is due to that `(<>)` is associative.

Any input outside of the domain falls in *don't care* situation.

### Operation

The elements of the domain shall be classified to 3 categories: **Negative**, **zero**, and **positive**.

- If the left operand is negative, output a negative value.
- If the left operand is zero:

  - If the right operand is negative, output a negative value.
  - If the right operand is zero, output a zero value.
  - If the right operand is positive, output a positive value.
- If the left operand is positive, output a positive value.

### Example

A Python 3 implementation of this operation:

```
lambda x,y: x if x != 0 else y
```

This has integers as the domain, and classifies integers by their signature.

Comment: looks like in many languages this will just be an "or" builtin

Comment: I want to say this might be clearer if the spec for the operation just used the names `LT`, `EQ`, and `GT`, but the example domain leads to the unfortunate revelation that your example solution could be simply `lambda x,y:x or y`...

Comment: @Wzl How would an "or" operator act? Bitwise "or" is commutative, while `(<>)` isn't.

Comment: Python 3: ````lambda x,y: x or y````

Comment: Finally, I am the outgolfer.

Comment: Javascript: `$=>_=>$||_`

Answer (score 0):

## Generate simultaneous equations [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

You've been tasked to write maths exam questions, but you're getting quite bored of coming up with simultaneous equations with integer solutions, so you decide to write a program to generate them. Because this is a school test, the questions mustn't be too easy, but they also mustn't be trivial.

The simultaneous equations should be of the form:

$$ ax + by = R $$
$$ cx + dy = S $$

where \$ a \$, \$ b \$, \$ c \$, \$ d \$, \$ R \$, \$ S \$ are integers. The equations must have exactly one set of solutions, the solutions must both be integers, and \$ x \$ must not equal \$ y \$.

The random generation method you choose is completely up to you, as long as there are at least 100 distinct equations that could be generated each with a non-zero probability. If the coefficients or equations are swapped, they count as the same (this is to discourage hard-coding of valid equations).

You may output in any reasonable format, such as a string `"-1x-2y=3;4x+5y=6"` or a list of 6 integers like `[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. The format must be consistent for all outputs.

### Examples

```
Valid              x   y
-------------------------
-1x-2y=0; 4x+5y=6  4  -2


Invalid              Notes
--------------------------
-1x-2y=7; 4x+5y=6    Non-integer solutions
-1.5x-3y=0; 4x+5y=6  Non-integer coefficients
0x+2y=8; 2x+2y=6     Zero coefficients
3x+4y=1; 6x+8y=2     Infinitely many solutions
3x+4y=1; 6x+8y=3     No solutions

TODO: add more examples
```

### Rules

- You may use any [reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

## Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too trivial

Comment: @tsh A lot of Kolmogorov questions are therefore even more "trivial".

Answer (score 0):

tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

## Based square-free words

A [square-free word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word) is a word that contains no squares, i.e. contains no adjacent repeating subwords. For example, `0123` is square-free, while `0112` and `012123` are not (because `11` and `1212` are repetitions, respectively).

In base-1 there is only one square-free word: `0`. In base-2 there are 6 square-free words: `0, 1, 01, 10, 010, 101`. In base-3 and up there are infinitely many.

### The challenge

Given a base `N` and a length `L`, output a square-free word of length `L` in base `N`, or a distinct falsy value (or an error) if no such word exists. Both the base and the length will be positive integers.
Alternatively, you may take an alphabet instead of a base as input, e.g. you may take `"ABC"` as an input instead of base-3 and give output in that alphabet.

Any reasonable input-output, standard restrictions, code golf.

### Test cases

Other similar outputs are also valid.

```
Base  Length  Output
2     1       0
2     2       01
2     3       010
2     4       Error or a distinct falsy value
3     4       0121
3     5       01210
3     50      01210212012101202102012021201021012010212021020120
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: This is a more general version of [this older, more specific question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146675/16484), is this unique enough to be a standalone question?

Answer (score 0):

## Gabriel's Horn

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226022/convince-me-gabriels-horn-is-possible)

Comment: 1. I don't think I've seen anything *very* similar. 2. Wording looks fine to me (mainly because the image helps a lot) 3. I don't have a strong opinion on this. Either way should be fine. 4. Looks correct. 5. Actually the whole challenge is simply "generate a specific arithmetic progression based on the input", which can be seen as not so interesting, and it has very little to do with Gabriel's Horn itself. Maybe a better title would be "Convince me Gabriel's Horn is possible"?

Answer (score 0):

Given an real polynomial equation \$c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n=0\$, count how many real roots it has.

You can and need to assume infinite precision. You can assume repeated root doesn't exist.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can take input [c0,c1,...,cn], [cn,...,c1,c0], or just the polynomial or the equation in your language support.

Test cases:

```
1=0 => 0
0=0 => Infinity
2+1x=0 => 1
3+4x+1x^2=0 => 2
6+4x+1x^2=0 => 0
0+0x+0x^2+1x^3+0x^4=0 => 1
```

## Sandbox Notes

[1] Is checking repeated root always possible?

Comment: This feels like a factorisation code-golf, though the question is still very good

Comment: @StackMeter But you can't solve some poly eq?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it is solvable in finite time?

Comment: Also, in your last example (`x^3=0` in simplified form), 0 is the repeated root.

Answer (score 0):

### Golf Code Golf

Given [the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/2011/1/28) (what I mean by full transcript is you can access all days of the transcript) of The Nineteenth Byte (the general chat room of code golf), output the full transcript in text form (you only have to include messages, though including other things is allowed. You can use any format as long as it includes the poster and contents of each message. As for people changing names, the way you handle this is up to you, do whichever is shortest). You can access the full transcript in your code, but you cannot access any other external sources.

Since this is code golf, shortest answer wins, and [standard loopholes are not allowed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/2011/1/28)

Comment: Any feedback would be helpful, since this is my first question idea here.

Comment: By "access the full transcript" what do you mean? There's no single page with the entire transcript, so do you mean all pages that are `https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/<date>`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes that is what I meant, I’ll update it now, thank you.

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about what "text form" is. I'm assuming `...people talk...` is not correct, but there are a huge amount of formats, such as `person: message` and `<person> message`, not even considering stars, multi-line messages, and users changing their usernames

Comment: @Wzl I edited it, is it more clear now or is there something I missed?

Comment: If people are as lazy as me I think they'll just output the raw HTML, since it complies with your constraints (however I think this is a good thing as answers shouldn't be required to parse HTML)

Answer (score 0):

## JS onelineriser

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

JavaScript is a very easy language to onelinerise. All one has to do is insert a semicolon in the correct locations and concatenate every line.

Your task is to write a program that, given a valid JS program, returns a program in one line but is otherwise identical to the input.

### Sandbox

- Clarifications?
- Any edge cases where any operation other than inserting semicolons is required?
- Should I include basic JS syntax in the question or provide a link?

Comment: I think you should ask the programs to minimize the amount of semicolons placed.

Comment: You definitely need to tell where one needs to insert `;`s.

Comment: I know where one *should* place semis but I'm not exactly clear whether those semis are *necessary*. However, I intended this to be a code-golf and not a code-challenge (shortest source)

Comment: Either the input code is guaranteed to conform to a format where some simple rules can be applied (and you'll have to include these rules in the challenge), or this is going to require a full parsing and syntax analysis -- which is probably far too complicated for a code-golf challenge.

Comment: Can I make the whole input toJson and then feed it to eval? This is valid since ES2019. (And CSP is never a part of ES specification, so that doesn't matter.)

Comment: Other than inserting semicolons: remove comments. For example, `foo(); // do something<line-break>bar();`. And remember to keep line break in comments. For example, `()=>{return//<line-break>42;}`. More terrible comments: `\`${()=>{return // this is a comment in template string. <line-break> }}\``. Even even terrible edge case: If [hashbang proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-hashbang) landed...

Comment: @tsh tbh comments aren't "code" so to speak, so I might not actually have those test cases. They would be hell to deal with.

Comment: Can I just warp the code `eval`? (ok also asked by tsh)

Answer (score 0):

## Print a BigNum

Your task is to take an **arbitrary precision** unsigned integer, separated into 7-bit parts (a.k.a. base 128), and output it in base 10.

### Rules:

All arithmetic for conversion (excluding basic indexing) must be done only using values \$-2^{15}\le x \le 2^{15}-1\$, or in simpler terms, the range of a signed 16-bit integer.

So for example, something like this in Python would be illegal because `a[i]<<i*7` and `sum` are capable of making a number larger than \$2^{15}-1\$.

```python
lambda a:str(sum(a[i]<<i*7for i in range(len(a))))
```

Note that you are not required to explicitly use 16-bit integers or mask every time.

Your algorithm must be able to handle numbers of any length, if the resources are available.

Assume all inputs to be valid and the shortest possible length.

### Input/output:

The input is a list of numbers, each 0-127, in big or little endian order. You only need to handle up to 224 bits, or 32 base 128 digits, though.

Any reasonable encoding format is fine, as long as all digits are in base 128 and the length is variable. You could do this: `122 bananas, 0 bananas, 20 bananas, 12 apples`, I don't care. ULEB128 is allowed if that is easier.

The output can be either an ASCII string or printed to standard output, all in base 10. These must be ordered in big endian (as if you were to print it).

### Test cases

Inputs are in little endian order.

```
[0] -> 0
[1] -> 1
[127] -> 127
[99] -> 99
[0, 0, 1] -> 16384
[127, 0, 0, 0, 127] -> 34091303039
[21, 26, 111, 58] -> 123456789
[1, 78, 123, 61, 102, 86, 17, 32, 74, 41, 114, 79, 1] -> 31415926535897932384626433
[63, 29, 51, 105, 61, 107, 45, 70, 105, 97, 38, 36, 121, 15, 77, 24, 72, 4, 52, 56, 6, 5, 36, 38, 87, 10, 37, 26, 96, 16, 21, 110] -> 23203475113112158652497114438750306328443726354045579113768791363263
```

Comment: What does "All calculations must use a maximum of 16 bits" exactly mean? Does it mean I can only use 16 bits RAM (including registers)?

Comment: You probably want to limit the absolute value, otherwise someone could calculate `-<ans>`, convert it to a string, and remove the first character

Comment: `Your algorithm must be able to handle numbers of any length given a large enough buffer.` So given a number with >2^15 base-128 digits how to access?

Answer (score 0):

## Return shortest integer-is-one-of function

[metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf)

This is a [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) challenge, where you'll ...

Given a number of integers as input, your task is to write a function in JS, which returns a function that checks if an inputted integer is any of those. For example, `f([1, 2, 4])` would return a function which would return `true` if given `1`, `2`, or `4`, and `false` for any other inputs.

**Task:**

Your function will take any nonzero number of integers. There will not be any duplicates. This should return either a function, or a string containing the function's code.

The returned function should take a single integer as input. If the input is one of the integers inputted into the original function, it should return a truthy value, and a falsy one otherwise. You may also choose to return any two consistent values, or a consistent value for one possiblity (such as `0` for truthy) and any other value for the other.

**Scoring:**

This is metagolf, meaning the average of the byte counts of the returned programs for a certain set of inputs will be your score. This set of inputs will consist of:

- All combinations one to four integers from `-10` to `10`
- A random group of 2000 inputs consisting of between five and ten integers between `-100` and `100`
- A random group of 1000 inputs consisting of between two and six integers between `-10000` and `10000`

Optimizing your solution for these specific test cases is disallowed.

## Meta

- I will generate a random list of test cases that will be used for scoring when I post this
- This is my first time writing a metagolf challenge. Any improvements y'all can think of?
- I think the number of bytes should be limited in the submitted function (not the generated ones). Suggestions?
- Too many test cases? Too few?

Comment: The option to return a function is only available in JS, I'm assuming? I think you should disallow it, because it's unclear how you measure the size of a function object.

Comment: Maybe you should include test cases with more than six integers? If not, is it allowed for a solution to be optimized for small sizes? (given that it's a a minority in the input space)

Comment: @CommandMaster Oh, I meant to restrict this to JS anyway, wasn't sure if I was going to do that or not. It should be possible in any language with first class functions, though. If I open it up to any language I'll allow returning a string with a program. I'll add some test cases with more items.

Comment: If you return a function, how do you count the byte count of it?

Comment: `.toString()` (plus it's pretty likely they'll return a string form of the function anyway)

Comment: `.toString()` doesn't work for that, for example in `function f(i) {
    var l = a=>a+i
    return x=>l(x)
}` `f().toString()` is just `x=>l(x)`, while that's clearly not the length of the code you want to count (it's also unclear what code you do want to count in such a case)

Comment: @CommandMaster The functions will need to be independent from the meta function. As in, no closures/accessing variables in the above scope.

Answer (score 0):

## What is the link to your answer?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential)

### Goal

Your task is to create a program taking the input that returns the link to your answer. You can find a link to your answer by clicking at the share button on your answer.

### Rules

1. Standard loopholes apply except for searching for the answer online. In fact, you are expected to find the answer online.
2. You are allowed to use curl or the equivalent, but you are not allowed to use any html parser library or built-in. If you need to import the library, the import declaration does **NOT** count into the code size as long as you don't rename any identifiers.
3. You are not allowed to assume the link to your answer. You have to search this page for your submission. If you remove your submission and readd it, and your code breaks, you fail the challenge.
4. You may still assume your username, the contents of your code, and the programming language/byte count you are using. You are not allowed to assume the description below your code. If you edit the description part of the submission and the code breaks, you fail the challenge. You may assume that the code of each submission is unique and no one copies your submission into another answer.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so, the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: What prevents me from simply hardcoding my output?

Comment: @StackMeter If you delete your answer, and post again the same answer, and it break, it fails the challenge.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: What if my language has built-in for HTML parser (Yes, JavaScript running in browsers , aka. BOM, does have one)? Also, what will happen if I post 2 answers to this question?

Comment: Can I assume no one else will contain my code as part of an answer/comment?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes

Comment: @tsh 1. You have to avoid using that built-in, 2. You have to be able to distinguish your submissions.

Comment: [tag: self-referential] ?

Answer (score 0):

## [Recreate the Stack Overflow logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226148/recreate-the-stack-overflow-logo)

Comment: note that [the last time this was attempted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4561/90614), it got closed

Comment: @Wzl this one is a [tag:code-golf] question. I don't see why it can be off-topic.

Comment: @Wzl also, the logo for this one is not the one specified from that question you linked.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## Lowest effort to fill the bucket

There are two man, Paul and Jhon, who can move only along a line; they are real persons so Paul cannot goes to the right of John and Jhon cannot goes to the left of Paul. At time 0 they start at the opposite ends of the line.

*Paul* |------X1----X2----BUCKET--------X3-----X4-----| *Jhon*

Their goal is to pickup the balls along the line (denoted as Xn) and fill the bucket in the lowest time. The time needed to go from A to B along the line is equal to the distance from A to B.

For the challenge the balls are 20 and they are located on the line in the following way:

0. Paul = 0
1. X1 = 1
2. X2 = 2
3. X3 = 3
4. x4 = X5 = x6 = 5
5. BUCKET = 8
6. X7 = 10
7. X8 = 11
8. X9 = X10 = X11 = 15
9. X12 = 20
10. X13 = X14 = X15 = 22
11. X16 = X17 = X18 = 28
12. X19 = 29
13. X20 = 30
14. Jhon = 32

Which is the best sequence to reach they goal?

Answer (score 0):

Back to the sandbox.

Challenge will be initially done on TBD, although I may do it again after that sometimes. Also, programs will be launched with a launcher shell script.

### Background/story

You are a programmer who has been requested to create a program that wipes out other similar programs. However, you need to have your program fight others to see how it does ***in the field***.

### Requirements

You are to make a program that can run on a  Debian 10 VM. If the language you use is not available by default on Debian 10, you must provide instructions or a link to the compiler.

#### Formatting

Submissions are to be formatted as follows:

````
# Name, Language

Description

```
Code
```

More description and explanation

Link to compiler download and/or download instructions for Debian 10 GNU/Linux (also add compiler options to use when compiling.)
````

#### Requirements for being included

Your answer must have at least one upvote. You also need to include an emergency off switch and test the switch to be included, and provide the source code and have tested it on a Debian 10 VM. Also, its growth rate must be hypothetically sub-exponential (this is to stop excessively laggy answers. If you don't know what growth rate to go with, go with linear (\$O(x)\$) or Polynomial (\$O(x^2)\$,\$O(x^3)\$,etc.).

### Victory

To win, you need to be the last process of the bunch, by killing other processes through a system call. If you kill important processes that result in the VM breaking, that round is ignored for scoring. A total of 100 rounds will be run, and you get a point if you are the last "malicious" process around. If there's a tie, the tiers will be put in a tiebreaker.

### Pseudocode for submission example

I don't know much about coding yet, so here's some pseudocode (feel free to convert it to a real programming language and mark it as such:

## Example, Pseudocode

This program simply kills processes with the word "MalicousProcess", unless it's "MalicousProcess-Example"

```
def Example () {
  while (system(ps aux | grep "MalicousProcess") != null) {
    for each process != "MalicousProcess-Example" {
      kill process
    }
  }
  return 0
```

[fictitious compiler](https://example.com)

Please provide more recommendations.

Comment: "This is to stop joke answers, suicidal answers (sorry EmoWolf), and malware if it shows up." I doubt it will stop joke answers (including EmoWolf).

Comment: Well, then it may stop bad joke answers and malware (like :(){ :|:& };:  ). Also, I sure hope stack exchange doesn't run all inputs through bash.

Comment: @4D4850 Don't worry about malware; we follow riules here :p

Comment: Ok Redwolf. I'll remove the justification part, but still keep the policy.

Comment: Also, this is a little off topic, but why's your comment the only one that appears when you don't expand the comments?

Comment: @4D4850 Redwolf's comment has been upvoted, so it is viewed by stack exchange as the most important/helpful/funny comment, and the others are less important

Comment: Anyway, can any of you provide any more recommendations, or do you think it's ready to be posted?

Comment: Disallowing a rate of O(e^x) doesn't disallow all exponential solutions. Is that intended? If not you should probably require it tl be subexponential

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll make that change now.

Comment: Provided no recommendations are made by Sunday 9:00 Central time, I'll post this question on the main site.

Comment: Ok, I'm posting the question.

Comment: Nevermind. Back to the Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

## Verify the Perfect Rectangle

According to [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectRectangle.html), a perfect rectangle is defined to be a rectangle that can be divided into squares of different side lengths.

In this challenge, we are going to verify whether or not an arrangement is a perfect rectangle.

For the input, there should be at least `3n+2` non-negative integers in it:

- The first two numbers should show the size of the rectangle.
- Rest of the `3n` numbers should describe `n` squares.
- Each square should be described with `3` numbers, which are the side length(>0) and the position(x, y).
- Position should be consistent throughout the whole input. For example, If the program gets the position of the bottom left corner of the square for one time, it should do that every other time as well.

For the output, the program should print a truthy value if the given arrangement is a perfect rectangle, and a falsey value otherwise.

- Every squares should be different in side length.
- There should be neither overlaps nor voids.

Test cases(Note that any input and output formats are acceptable if they are reasonable):

```
[[32,33],[9,0,0],[8,9,0],[15,17,0],[10,0,9],[1,9,8],[7,10,8],[14,0,19],[4,10,15],[18,14,15]]
-> True #This is the first example in the above link. 

[[65,47],[23,0,0],[17,23,0],[25,40,0],[6,23,17],[11,29,17],[24,0,23],[5,24,23],[19,24,28],[3,40,25],[22,43,25]]
-> True #This is the second example in the above link. 

[[4,4],[2,0,0],[2,2,0],[2,0,2],[1,2,2],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,2,3]]
-> False #There are sqaures of same sizes. 

[[5,5],[3,0,0],[3,2,2],[2,0,3],[1,3,1],[1,3,0],[1,7,0]]
-> False #There are overlaps and voids.
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), which means that codes with least bytes win.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a non-renewable world

In [Minecraft](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us), we can split all possible items into two categories: *renewable* and *non-renewable*. All non-renewable items are simply items that are not renewable.

Minecraft worlds are not infinite, meaning that, for some resources, there are only a finite number available. This number is often *huge*, but it is finite. For example, [diamond ore](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Diamond_Ore) can only be obtained by mining blocks that are generated when the world is created, meaning that there is only a finite number of them in any given world.

However, some resources can be obtained infinitely. For example, as [Raid Captains](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Raid_captain) will spawn indefinitely, it is possible to obtain an arbitrarily large number of [Ominous Banners](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Ominous_Banner), dropped when you kill a Raid Captain. Or, as you can create an infinite water source, and you can get infinite iron by killing [Iron Golems](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_golem), it is possible to get an infinite number of [Water Buckets](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Water_Bucket).

Any resource for which it is possible to obtain an arbitrary amount of is called *renewable*, and there are a [lot of these](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_renewable_resources). Any item that is not renewable is *non-renewable*. There are [40 of these](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Non-renewable_resource) that are obtainable in a classic Minecraft 1.16 survival world. They are:

```
A Netherite Tool               Netherite Armor                Ancient Debris                 Block of Diamond              
Block of Netherite             Coal Ore                       Cobweb                         Conduit                       
Dead Bush                      Diamond                        Diamond Ore                    Dragon Egg                    
Dragon Head                    Elytra                         Emerald Ore                    Enchanted Golden Apple        
Enchantment Table              Gilded Blackstone              Gold Ore                       Heart of the Sea              
Iron Ore                       Jukebox                        Lapis Lazuli Ore               Large Fern                    
Lava Bucket                    Lodestone                      Nether Gold Ore                Netherite Ingot               
Netherite Scrap                Iron/Gold/Diamond Horse Armor  Pigstep Music Disc             Quartz Ore                    
Redstone Ore                   Shulker Box                    Shulker Shell                  Snout Banner Pattern          
Sponge                         Tall Grass                     Thing Banner Pattern           Wet Sponge
```

Your task is to get as many of these 40 items as you can. `A Netherite Tool` means any of a Netherite Sword, Pickaxe, Axe, Shovel or Hoe. `Netherite Armor` is any of a Netherite helmet, Chestplate, Leggings or Boots. `Iron/Gold/Diamond Horse Armor` means that any of these three are acceptable. Leather Horse Amor is not.

---

You should create a vanilla Minecraft Java Edition world, in 1.16.5, in Hardcore difficulty. You then have until you die in that world to collect all 40 of these items, or as many as you can. You should provide a double chest containing 1 of each of these and nothing else.

In order to verify attempts, you should provide the [save file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/14702/203063) of your world, as a [zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)).

The user who gets the most of these 40 items before dying wins. If multiple users get all 40 items, the user who gets all 40 within the fewest [in-game days](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Daylight_cycle), which can be found by pressing F3.

### Rules

- You may not change the game rules of the world from the default, nor may you change any other option during world creation aside from the seed. To be fully clear, you may change exactly 3 things from the default values after clicking "Create New World":

  - The name of the world
  - The gamemode, switching from Survival to Hardcore
  - Optionally, the seed, which may be any value of your choosing
- While in the world, you may not enable commands. This is typically done by pausing the game, opening the world to LAN and enabling commands, but, regardless of how you may do it, enabling commands is completely forbidden.
- You may not use any mods, datapacks or anything else that can modify the default behaviour of the game. Texture packs are perfectly fine.
- I will be testing and confirming each world submitted, so you should not include anything in the save file that isn't generated by the world. You may not edit the save file directly, only by interacting with the world
- Items are allowed to be enchanted, renamed or otherwise legitimately modified in game

---

Additionally, as of snapshot [21w20a](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition_21w20a), there are 18 new non-renewable resources (ignoring products from Deepslate and Cobbled Deepslate), and Lava Buckets are noew renewable:

```
Block Of Raw Copper        Block Of Raw Gold         
Block Of Raw Iron          Budding Amethyst          
Calcite                    Cobbled Deepslate         
Copper Ore                 Deepslate                 
Deepslate Diamond Ore      Deepslate Gold Ore        
Deepslate Iron Ore         Deepslate Lapis Lazuli Ore
Deepslate Redstone Ore     Raw Copper                
Raw Gold                   Raw Iron                  
Spore Blossom              Tuff
```

This brings the total number of non-renewable items in the latest version to 57

I will offer a +500 bounty to a submission which **also** includes a save file for a world which:

- Is a vanilla Minecraft Java Edition snapshot 21w20a Hardcore world
- Meets the requirements for the main challenge
- Has 3 chests with all 57 non-renewable items, as listed above

---

## Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- Are there any ways this can be exploited, so that users can trivialise the task? How can I prevent those exploits?
- Is it a good challenge?
- Tags are [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) and [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) ([meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22330/tag-proposal-minecraft)). Any suggestions?
- Minecraft is [not free](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/get-minecraft), thus limiting those who can compete. Is this a significant problem?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: I don't think minecraft being not free is a relevant problem here

Comment: I'm sure I saw a way to renew Spore Blossoms in one of the recent snapshots

Comment: There are, frankly, trivial ways to exploit this system. For it to be more or less uncheatable you would need a speedrun-style verification system requiring full screen recording and ideally livestreaming for the whole thing. I don't think it's a good fit for the site, to be honest, because there's really nothing code-related about it (**Code** Golf and **Coding** Challenges), and because it's too complex to implement a reliable verification system. You could try proposing it as a [category extension on speedrun.com](https://speedrun.com/mcce), though

Comment: Honestly this might be better as an off-TNB hosted competitive event where a bunch of people can stream (to minimize cheating) and attempt to get [as many of] these resources [as quickly as possible], if we want this to be a thing for people in this community to do for fun. In any case, this was a cool idea initially, but I do agree with pxeger that there isn't really anything in scope for CGCC about this.

Comment: Is Bedrock allowed?

Comment: If you do make it a TNB event (or even if you don't?), maybe the scoring system should take into account the rarity of each item. So coal ore scores 1 point and enchanted golden apple scores 10 or something

Comment: Question - are we allowed to start with anything, as long as we get the items from the world itself?

Answer (score 0):

## `for (a.length of a)` [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

A recent [conversation in The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/js-array-looping-jankiness) about language design brought about discussion of an "interesting" snippet of JavaScript code:

```js
for (a.length of a) console.log(a)
```

This loops over the elements of `a`, but assigns each element to the length of `a`, and prints out `a` on each iteration.

- When an array's length is assigned, it is resized to the length, with excess elements being removed from the end, and additional elements filled with `undefined`
- When an array's length is assigned to `undefined`, an error occurs
- The loop will halt if the number of iterations is ever greater than `a.length`

Depending on the contents of `a`, this produces some wild results.

TODO: finish this post. Posted without finishing to test if Redwolf Program's Sandbox Posts bot is working :)

Answer (score 0):

## Is someone eavesdropping? (WIP)

Alice and Bob, who are quantum physicists, are being watched by Eve, a quantum FBI agent. Eve has quantum tunneled underneath Bob's house and is tapping all his quantum channels. Luckily, Alice and Bob are using the [BB84 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) to exchange quantum keys to encode their quantum messages. Your job is to write a program/function to help Alice and Bob determine if Eve is evesdropping.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert Lambda Calculus to SKI-notation

[Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) is a formal system in mathematical logic for expressing computation based on function abstraction and application using variable binding and substitution.

However, it's possible to translate pure lambda calculus into SKI-notation. This can be preformed by building an AST for the lambda calculus, converting it through multiple substitution steps where it contains a mixture of lambda calculus and SKI-notation, until a pure SKI-notation expression is reached.

As this is code golf, there is some flexibility on your I/O so that you may be able to accept the lambda calculus and output the SKI-notation as a tree but the examples will use a string-based notation.

- `(c1)`, where `c1` is an arbitrary expression that does not contain a lambda (represented here by `>`), does not require further substitution.
- `(c1(c2))`, where `c1` and `c2` are arbitrary expressions, can be substituted with `(s1(s2))`, where `s1` and `s2` are the result of performing any necessary substitutions on `c1` and `c2`.
- `(x1>x1)` can be substituted with `I`.
- `(x1>c1)` (where `c1` can be an arbitrary expression as long as it does not contain a reference to `x1`) can be substituted with `(Ks1)`, where `s1` is the result of performing any necessary substitutions on `c1`.
- `(x1>(x2>x1))` can be substituted with `K`.
- `(x1>(x2>e1))` (where `e1` is an arbitrary expression that is depends on but is not `x1`) can be substituted by performing substitutions on `(x2>e1)` resulting in `s2` and then performing substitutions on `(x1>s2)`.
- `(x1>c1(e2))` (where `c1` can be an arbitrary expression as long as it does not contain a reference to `x1`) can be substituted with `(s1(s2))`, where `s1` and `s2` are the result of performing any necessary substitutions on `c1` and `(x1>e2)`.
- `(x1>e1(e2))` can be substituted with `(S(s1)(s2))`, where `s1` and `s2` are the result of performing any necessary substitutions on `(x1>e1)` and `(x1>e2)`.

Naturally function application associates left-to-right, so in the case of `(x1>c1(c2)(e3)(c4))` this needs to be substituted using the last rule as if it was `(x1>(c1(c2)(e2))(c4))`, which requires generating substitutions for `(x1>c1(c2)(e2))` and `(x1>c4)`, but then `(x1>c1(c2)(e2))` can use the penultimate rule, turning into `c1(c2)(x1>e2)`, with `(x1>e2)` still needing to be substituted.

Given an input expression of lambda calculus, please convert it to SKI-notation. You must use the above substitutions at a minimum, but you can perform additional reductions if you wish, so for instance if you use a string-based notation then you may simplify `((S)(K))` to `(SK)` or even `SK` depending on context.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins.

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to whether we can output any SKI expression so long as it is equivalent to the input and you are just laying out an example algo or whether we have to output the result of that algo (plus optional substitutions).

Comment: I think also a definition of what it means to be equivalent between the two systems and within the systems themselves would be helpful.

Comment: @WheatWizard You have to show that you do no worse than the example aglo. In theory the post will have enough examples so that you just need to be able to match or beat all of the examples.

Comment: I'll have to work on that definition because I don't want to accidentally be too restrictive or indeed lenient.

Comment: Closely related: [unrestricted conversion challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112115/78410), [metagolf version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105991/78410)

Answer (score 0):

## Can we measure time?

You have 2 hourglasses with sand lying at bottom in both of hourglass, one that is \$1\$ sec hourglass(call it \$A\$) and other is \$\sqrt2\$ sec hourglass (call it \$B\$)

(A hourglass is said to be n second hour glass if time taken by all of the sand of hourglass to fall from top to bottom is n second)

Now we are given 2 integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ such that
$$T=a+b\sqrt2 > 0$$
assume:$$\ 1000000\geq a \geq -1000000$$

$$\ 1000000\geq b \geq -1000000$$

we need to respond that can we measure this time  \$T\$ with our hourglasses? ("YES" or "NO")

Some clarifications and definitions:

- We say we can measure time \$t\$ if at that instance in at least one of hourglass sand have just stopped falling.
- We can make a hourglass upside down(any number of time) if and only if at least one of the hour glass has empty top.
- Assume time taken to invert a hourglass is 0 sec.(by invert means upside down,i.e the sand that was in bottom is now at top and the sand at top is now at bottom).
- If at least one of hourglass sand have just stopped falling we can report this instant as the amount of time measured.
- If sand on both the hour glass is at bottom and we decided to do no any operation, then it is assumed that we are reporting the time measured at this instance and the process stops.

Example 1:

\$a=0\$ and \$b=1\$

Our answer is true, because initially both the hourglass is given with sand at bottom and  at the start we can invert B, so when the sand from B has fallen all to bottom at that instance a total of \$\sqrt2\$ time has passed and we can report it,hence we have measured \$\sqrt2\$ time.

Example 2:

\$ a=-1\$ and \$b=2\$

\$T = -1 +\sqrt2\$
Our answer is true, we can obtain it as follows:
At time 0, turn both A and B upside down, At 1 sec A will be emptied to bottom, turn A upside down again (B remain falling as it was), now when B fall completely,turn A upside down, now when A empties the total duration is \$-1 +\sqrt2\$.

1(All the A falls, at this instance B is left with \$-1+\sqrt2\$ )
$$+$$
\$\sqrt2\$-1 (at this duration after the previous one B have fallen completely and A is left with \$1-(-1+\sqrt2)\$  at top, but we have inverted it so that means A is actually left with \$-1+\sqrt2\$ at top)
$$+$$

\$-1+\sqrt2\$ (at this duration after the previous one A have fallen completely)

we can report this instant, the total time is:

\$(1)+(-1+\sqrt2)+(-1+\sqrt2)=-1 +2\sqrt2 \$

And for following input it is not possible to measure and you have to output "NO"

\$a=11\$ , \$b=-5\$

\$a=35\$ , \$b=-21\$

\$a=-4\$ , \$b=4\$

\$a=-8815\$ , \$b=6261\$

\$a=-1\$ , \$b=1\$

.
.
.

### [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

> The idea of this problem is not my original, it appeared in a coding competition some time back.

Comment: Thanks @pxeger for editing.

Comment: You should provide some impossible cases?

Comment: Thanks, I have added.

Answer (score 0):

## Is this  a trivial brainfuck NOP? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem) [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)

Brainfuck is Turing-complete<sup>[*](https://t.pxeger.com/xs.html?t=ackchyually&v=well,+except+for+the+3000+cell+limit+that+the+original+spec+imposed,+and+the+obvious+limits+of+practical+computation)</sup>, which means determining the behaviour of an arbitrary program is undecidable. However, we can get arbitrarily close to this if we limit ourselves to detecting a limited subset of programs.

For this challenge, we will detect a limited subset of NOPs - that is, snippets of programs which have no effect including on the brainfuck interpreter's state - which I have declared "trivial NOPs".

Here is a recursive definition of a trivial NOP:

- the empty string is a trivial NOP
- snippets consisting only of characters outside the set `[]<>+-,.` (that is, characters which are ignored in Brainfuck), are trivial NOPs
- the concatenation of two trivial NOPs is also a trivial NOP
- snippets of any of the following forms, where `X` is another trivial NOP, are also trivial NOPs:

  - `+X-`
  - `-X+`
  - `<X>`
  - `>X<`

We will assume brainfuck has unlimited tape length. Overflow also does not need to be considered, because if a cell rolls over due to a `+`, a `-` can then underflow it back and it will still be a NOP.

Any snippet containing `,` or `.` is not a NOP because it performs impure I/O, and any snippet containing `[` or `]` is undecidable, so must be assumed to be not a NOP.

Your task is to, given a brainfuck snippet as a string or list of characters, determine whether it is a trivial NOP, and output two distinct values corresponding to true and false.

### Test-cases

#### Truthy

```
(empty string)
a
+-
<>-+
<!>
+<-+>-
<<<+++a+--++>><-+>>
```

#### Falsey

```
<+>+<->-             (note: even though this is a NOP, it's not a trivial NOP)
+<-+>-[]
,+<-+>-
<.>
```

### Rules

- You may assume the input string always consists only of printable ASCII excluding space
- You may use [any reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

## Meta

- Can you think of any other classes of brainfuck snippet that are simple to detect as doing nothing?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: "the concatenation of two trivial NOPs is also a trivial NOP" so maybe include a simple test case like : `+-<>`

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched (not sure if this is a dupe of any existing question in [balanced-string + decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string+decision-problem)

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/bracket-balancing (also included in above search link). Your question is equals to "does the input contains `[` or the input have matched `-+` `<>` as balanced `bracket'?"

Answer (score 0):

## Conic Sections (simplified)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [characteristics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characteristics)

---

Given the equation of a non-parabolic conic section, output its characteristics.

---

## Spec

This assumes prior knowledge of hyperbolas and ellipses, as well as their characteristics. (This includes circles; they are a special case of the ellipse with eccentricity of zero.)

### Input

A non-parabolic (to simplify things) conic section given in the standard equation form. To simplify things further (because the main point is not to perform linear algebra magic) there will be no `xy` term. This is an example of a valid equation:

```
x^2+6x+y^2-8y+15=0 // string form
[1,6,1,-8,15]      // array form
```

These are not:

```
x^3+5x^2+7x+4=0 // because the degree of the equation is 2
x^2+5xy+y^2-4=0 // because there should be no `xy` term
x^2+3x+7=0      // because there should be `x` and `y` terms.
```

Note that the conic section can also be taken as an array as shown above. If so, please specify the order of the array; I am flexible when it comes to this format, As long as there are 5 elements with nonexistent terms represented by zero (like no `y` term in `x^2+5x+y^2+14=0`) and that the terms they represent are `x^2 x y^2 y c` where `c` is a constant. The equation will always be `<expression> = 0`.

### Output

Output should be the type of section, center, horizontal radius, vertical radius, foci and eccentricity (in whatever desired order). This can be output as a string or an array as long as it is clear. A valid output for `x^2+6x+y^2+8y+16=0` (or its array equivalent) would be:

```
["ellipse", [-3, -4], 3, 3, [[-3, -4]], 0]
```

or

```
ellipse
-3 -4
3
3
-3 -4
0
```

or similar.

(no need to output "circle" because it is a special case of the ellipse)

### Meta:

- duplicate?
- should I edit in info on conic sections?
- should I create the `characteristics` tag?

Comment: One issue with the `x^2+5xy+y^2-4=0`: It **is a valid conic section** (hyperbola).

Comment: @fasterthanlight I know, but we are not considering `xy` terms in this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pickleball Doubles Scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226591/66833)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and thanks for using the Sandbox! I've fixed some formatting for you - on our site, you have to use `\$` instead of `$` for MathJax. At the moment, this challenge is missing an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8130) - I'm guessing you want [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @pxeger:  Thank you.  Yes, I was thinking code golf.  Would it be better to take the END state as [0,0,0] so that the format of all inputs is the same?  Is there a place to get the standard verbiage for code golf?

Comment: Yes, I think `[0, 0, 0]` is a good idea - but I think the best option is to allow answers to choose a value to represent the END state depending on their language (in some it may be easier to use `null`, or take a string or something...). Re verbiage, there's [Standard definitions of terms within specifications](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324/), but you can also just look at the various [meta-tag:policy] posts for more information. If you have specific questions, you can always ask in our chatroom, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240).

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## What sequence? [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Stack Exchange distinguishes users by a unique id that can be found in their their profile URL.

You can find your id by navigating to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/current and finding the number after the `/users/` bit in the resulting URL. For example, my profile URL is `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99744/alex-bries`, so my user ID is `99744`

You can use this id to look up the number sequence of the last submitter on OEIS:

> The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences® ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/)) is an online database containing integer sequences. These sequences are identified via an id starting with an A followed by 6 numbers. You can search for an id with the "id:" key on the search bar of OEIS.
> id:A99744 will display sequence A099744 followed by all other sequences that mention it.

Your job is to write a program that, when given a number n, produces the nth number in sequence of the submitter above.

#### Rules

- Each language may only be used once.
- You may not post 2 answers in a row
- Every next submision may only be max 10 bytes higher than the previous one
- The champion is the last valid submission on june 14th

golfing is not a requirement but it is in your favour

Comment: Different OEIS sequences have vastly different complexity. I'm pretty sure my user id is solvable in 6 bytes of Jelly, which can break the whole game depending on the next user's id.

Comment: @Bubbler I like the idea of different complexities, but not sure how to prevent the colossal differences. Personally i like it, but if you have ny suggestions for how to improve, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think this works as a [answer-chaining] challenge, but it could work as just a regular code-golf challenge (i.e. write a program which takes an integer `n` and outputs the `n`th term of the sequence with your id). It's unlikely to be fair, but its better than [answer-chaining]. I've also done a bit of editing, feel free to change anything I did

Comment: Yes, that's probably the better desicion, but after thinking about it more, its unlikely to be very fun, so ill leave it (for now). Thanks for the the constructive feedback guys.

Comment: Using user IDs is inherently unfair.

Answer (score 0):

## [Optimize imnotdeadfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226873/optimize-imnotdeadfish)

Comment: Deadfish (at least, the original one) used `i` and `d` intead of `+` and `-`. Is there a reason you chose to use them?

Comment: @pxeger originally for the language I was going to have an input command so I swapped i and d for + and -, and I guess I never added them back.

Answer (score 0):

[Yet another digit insertion problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229165/yet-another-digit-insertion-problem)

Answer (score 0):

## [Random Prisoner's Trilemma - Python 3 KOTH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229155/random-prisoners-trilemma-python-3-koth)

Answer (score 0):

## branch golfing: sort a list by number of prime factors

Specifically, first sorted by total number of prime factors, with any
ties broken by number of unique prime factors (remove this?), then broken by size. The list will never contain 1.

Test cases:

```
[4,5,6,9] -> [5,4,9,6]
[10,11,12] -> [11,10,12]
[360 200 12] -> [12 200 360]
[63 64 65] -> [65 63 64]
```

Comment: Please avoid challenges involving [the prime numbers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/43319).

Comment: Please avoid challenges where the scoring criteria relies on [non-observable program requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/43319).

Comment: Please avoid [making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/43319).

Comment: Also, thank you for using the sandbox! :-)

Comment: @Adám Do you have any example of something where it isn't clear whether or not it is a conditional branch? Or any advice that isn't essentially just "this is bad"?

Comment: Maybe. Are there any branches in [this APL solution](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXokdd7Y96VzzqmPGot/tR71qdR71LH3UuAvE7Vh1aART5n/aobcKj3r5HXc2Petc86t1yaL3xo7aJj/qmBgc5A8kQD8/g/2kKJgqmCmYKllxpCoYGCoaGCoZGAA)? The code means: `⊢` the input `⊇⍨` permuted `∘⍋` according to a grade using `⍭` prime factors for each `,` followed by `⍥≢` when counted, `∘∪` the unique `¨` for each, `⍭` prime factors for each. Or in other words: *Reorder according to a grading of prime factor count and then unique prime factor count.*

Comment: From your description, `⍭` sounds like a loop construct, which I intended to include, but I could clarify.

Comment: If you count loop constructs, would you also count APL's `+` as a loop? It automatically loops over its arguments: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBIYKRgrGCtoKJgYKpgYKZgZc5goWCpZAAUMDAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") Besides, you state that "Builtin functions are presumed to be branchless."

Comment: No. It loops its own code, but can't be used to perform arbitrary code in a loop.

Comment: My usage of `⍭` was exactly parallel to any usage of `+`. They both auto-loop. However, `¨` is in fact an explicit loop. I could probably code around that too, though. An example would be extracting the odd numbers from a list. In many languages, you'd use a loop with a branch, but in APL you'd write `List/⍨2|List` which means `L` where 2 divides the list ['s elements; that's implicit]. Looping? Branching? Anyway, you get the idea. It'll be next to impossible to determine for every language (there are lots!) what exactly constitutes an explicit loop, or for that sake a branch.

Comment: @Adám so they are analogous to functions that take 2 arrays as input and provide one as output? that doesn't seem like a branch to me. "I could probably code around that too, though." Yeah that's kinda the point of the challenge.

Comment: @Adám "but in APL you'd write List/⍨2|List which means L where 2 divides the list ['s elements; that's implicit]."  this explanation isn't very clear. this seems like this construct  (or pair of constructs, which you are confusingly explaining as one) is some kind of predicate filter/map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125052/discussion-between-adam-and-binarycat).

Answer (score 0):

## How much faster than qsort can you achieve?

## Task

Sort 1 million 32 bit integers as quickly as possible. Your code must create 1 million random non-negative integers in the range 0 to 999999 and sort them. Only the sorting should be timed.

## Score

I will run your code and compare the timings to my default C code using qsort. That is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main(void) {
    int sz;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Enter the size of array::");
    scanf("%d",&sz);
    uint32_t *arr = malloc (sz * sizeof(uint32_t));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
        arr[i]=rand()%1000000; 
    clock_t begin = clock();
    qsort(arr, sz, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f seconds\n", time_spent);
    printf("%d\n", arr[10]);
    return 0;
}
```

Your score will be the timing for my C code divided by the timing for your code.   I will run both on my PC. This means I will need clear instructions for how to compile and run your code on linux.

This means you will have to provide timing code in your solution so I am not timing the creation of the data.

## Current timings

On my PC:

- The sample C code takes 0.11 seconds.
- Python `sorted` takes 0.24 seconds.

## Notes

My code prints out one of the elements of the sorted array. This is to stop the opimizing compiler from removing the sorting code completely. You will have to do the same.

Builins **are** allowed.  As ever this is a challenge per language so if your Python answer is faster than any other Python answer you have won that mini-competition.
[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Comment: Obligatory question - builtins, yea or nay?

Comment: That's probably the wisest choice - probably want to edit the post to say that.

Comment: I strongly disagree with banning builtins. If any builtin is faster, either the builtin is interesting enough to be posted, or the challenge is boring. Banning builtins won't improve the latter, but it will hurt the former

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I can go with that.

Comment: @StackMeter I deleted my comment as bultins are going to be allowed.

Comment: I would argue that "only time sorting should be timed" is a bit unclear. Consider my code is: `int counts[MAX],i,j,k,sort(*a,size){for(i=0;i<size;++i)++counts[a[i]];for(i=k=0;i<MAX;counts[i++]=0)for(j=counts[i];j--;)a[k++]=i;}` (maybe some typos here, not tested) the initialize of `counts` array is required by sort. But C compiler will help me do so even begin `main()` entry and would probably not timed by my code.

Comment: @tsh what would you suggest?

Comment: Things to consider: 1) 32-bit signed or unsigned integers? Do I have a choice? 2) 32-bit (or any finite-sized) integers can be sorted using non-comparison sort algorithms, such as radix sort (which is asymptotically faster than any kind of comparison-based sort). Would you allow the answers to exploit this or not?

Answer (score 0):

## Finite Composition of Univariate Functions [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Problem

Given
$$\mathbb{F}:=\{f_i \mid f_i : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\}$$
the set of all the real maps, and the n-ary function composition

\begin{gather}
c_o(f_i) = f_1∘f_2∘f_3⋯∘f_n\\[8pt]
∀f_i ∈ \mathbb{F},~~~1≤i≤n∈\mathbb{N}
\end{gather}

write a program which receives n functions of a real variable as the input and computes the in-order function composition, product of all the entered functions as a string.

As standard, `x` is the name of the parameter variable in each function. Any other literal is taken as a constant.

### Examples

#### Example 1

input

```
number of functions: 3
f_1 = x + 1
f_2 = x - 10
f_3 = x^2 + 2
```

output

```
c_o(f_1,f_2,f_3) = ((x^2 + 2) - 10) + 1
```

#### Example 2

input

```
number of functions: 4
f_1 = 27x - sin(e)
f_2 = -7(x^2 + 1)^(1/2) 4y^3 + 21
f_3 = x^(3/2) + 4
f_4 = ln(z + 1)
(z, y, e are assumed as constants in the reals)
```

output

```
c_o(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4) = 27(-7(((ln(z + 1))^(3/2) + 4)^2 + 1)^(1/2) 4y^3 + 21) - sin(e)
```

Comment: Any suggestion, improvement? please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox! This seems like an interesting idea, but currently it is too underspecified to be clear. For example, the test cases imply that the input to each function is represented by `x`, but you haven't stated anywhere that we can assume that. Consider also a slight change to one of your cases, where one function has `-y(x^2 + 1)`. Is `y` a function or a constant? There are too many specifics, so hopefully the general idea gets across that you must specify how you are representing the functions very precisely for this to work.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you. I have edited it so that there's no ambiguity.

Comment: That is a good change, but doesn't address the ambiguity in separating functions like `sin` from the product of constants. It also isn't clear to me whether `x^2 - 7` is a valid solution for the first example. These have some overlap in that they (probably?) won't affect a solution that just substitutes the functions appropriately, but will affect any symbolic parser based approach.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman oh, yes, it's valid but it isn't required to go to such depths as to simplify symbolic expressions, that would be a problem on its own. I didn't specify so in the challenge and as for sin or those functions, since the problem to be addressed is the composition of functions any expression different from `x` should be "disregarded". I don't intend to make further computations with the output string.

Comment: What I'm trying to communicate is that your "point" for writing the challenge doesn't really matter - in some language it probably would be better to use a parser. If you just want to say "no other assumptions about the form of the function can be made" that is fine - but you have to actually say it, otherwise your challenge is unclear because I won't be able to tell if a solution is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

## Smallest number of actions to change reputation by [x] points

`8`: Upvote + downvote

`75`: Bounty + upvote + accepted answer

*Draft*

Comment: Potentially a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125804/get-me-back-down-to-1-rep). Stoopid.

Comment: @lyxal This one's about positive or negative rep gains though, so it's more general

Answer (score 0):

## Boxes in boxes in boxes in boxes.....

ASCII boxes are fun, but the box drawing questions seem to be limited insofar as that they seem to take a specific set of boxes. Today, I hope to fix that.
The challenge here is to write a program that takes a list of sides of boxes and characters to draw them with, and outputs the boxes.

To clarify some format issues:

### Input

Input is flexible, and will look like 1) this

```
17

30 20 #$5

21 15 $%^

19 13 311

...
```

or 2) this

```
[17, [30, 20, "#$5], [21, 15, "$%^], [19, 13, "311"], ...]
```

You may support either or both of these types, but you must be consistent with this choice.

Input is given in this order:

The first number, a single number on one line, is the number of boxes to place.

Then, for as many times as said first number, you will receive 2 numbers and three characters - the two numbers represent length and width, in any order. The three characters represent, in this order:

1. The character to use for the corners.
2. The character to use for the edges.
3. The character to fill the inside of the boxes.

The boxes should not overlap, but you have the freedom to place the boxes wherever you wish. The allowed symbols are `!$%^&*()_-+=#~/?\@s`, where the s represents space and in order to aid those who want to split on whitespace.

Input will be space separated within boxes and newline separated between boxes.

### Output

Output should be a set of boxes, conforming to the regulations and conditions above - for example,

```
%###%
#***# *((*
#***# ())(
#***# ())(
%###% *((*
```

for the input

```
2

5 5 %#*

4 4 *()
```

or

```
[2, [5, 5, "%#*"], [4, 4, "*()"]
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in bytes wins. Share your favourite drawings with your answer.

Additional tags: [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

### Meta

Any issues?

Should the scoring be [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)?

Is the challenge specified enough?

Comment: Your scoring shouldn't be pop-con. Also, you realise  people are just going to draw all the boxes newline-separated? Be clearer that the input format is flexible.

Comment: @Ausername let me go fix that

Comment: @Ausername Should I add a bounding box to stop people just seperating the boxes by newlines

Comment: I'm not saying anything's wrong with that, just that's how people are going to do it because it's the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

## Interpret Unreadable [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

---

## Introduction

[Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable) is a programming language designed to be – as the name states – unreadable (in most fonts, anyway). Instructions are `'` followed by a run of `"`s. So while in a code block, `'""'""'"""` looks just fine, it looks like '""'""'""" outside of one - it is extremely difficult to tell what is going on.

The instructions are prefix, and are as so:

| Instruction | Arity | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `'"` | Unary | Print; output the character with codepoint `x`, and return `x`. |
| `'""` | Unary | Increment; return `x+1`. |
| `'"""` | Nilary | Unit; return `1`. |
| `'""""` | Binary | Both; evaluate and disregard `x`, and return the result of evaluating `y`. |
| `'"""""` | Binary | While; keep evaluating `y` until `x` is `0`. Return the last result of evaluating `y`. |
| `'""""""` | Binary | Set; set the `x`th variable to `y`, and return `y`. |
| `'"""""""` | Unary | Get; return the value of the `x`th value. Undefined is `0`. |
| `'""""""""` | Unary | Decrement; return `x-1`. |
| `'"""""""""` | Ternary | If-else; if `x` is `0`, return `z`. Otherwise, return `y`. |
| `'""""""""""` | Nilary | Input; return the codepoint of the next character of input. EOF is `-1`. |

For example, a cat program would be:

```
'"""""'""'""""""'"""'""""""""""'"'"""""""'"""
while(++ setvar(1 = input())) {print(getvar(1))}
```

Or, in its unreadable glory: '"""""'""'""""""'"""'""""""""""'"'"""""""'"""

## Challenge

Given a valid Unreadable program and its input separated by any non-`'` or `"` character, interpret the program as Unreadable code.

## Test cases (uses `!` as the separation character, I/O is represented in [`CP-437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437))

```
Input -> Output
'"'"""!this input does nothing lol -> ☺
'"""""'""'""""""'"""'""""""""""'"'"""""""'"""!This is a cat so I can output whatever I want. blah blah blah... -> This is a cat so I can output whatever I want. blah blah blah...
'""""'""""'""""""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""'"""""""'"""'""""'""""""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'"""'""""'"'""'""'"""""""'""'"""'""""'"'""'"""""""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"'"""""""'""'""'"""'""""'"'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""" -> Hello, world!
'""""""'"""'""'""""""""""'""""""'""'"""'""""""""""'"'"""""'""""""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'"""'""""""'""'"""'""'"""""""'""'"""!A! -> b
```

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- A single trailing newline is allowed in the output, and no other trailing whitespace.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where it would be trivial to do this, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!
- **A +100 rep bounty will be given to the first Unreadable answer.**

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly interesting challenge to me, to be honest. Decoding the program into commands is fairly trivial (split by `'` and find lengths of each), in both golfing and practical languages, and the actual interpreting part of the challenge is basically the same as any other language.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms The interesting part is that commands are prefix, so it might take some thought to make an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert permutations to integers and back again

[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations) [encode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encode) [decode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decode)

Convert a permutation of 0,...,n-1 to a number in the range 0,...,n!-1, and convert back again.

### Task

Write a program containing two functions (or two programs).

The first function should accept a permutation (i.e. an ordering) of the numbers 0,1,2,...,n-1 (where n is any positive integer) and output an integer in the range 0,1,...,n!-1 (where n! is n factorial).  Distinct permutations of the same length n must produce distinct outputs, but there are no further restrictions.

The second function should implement the inverse of the first function (except that it also needs to know n).  It should accept an integer k in the range 0,1,...,n!-1 AND a positive integer n, and should output the permutation of 0,1,2,...,n-1 that yields k when sent to the first function.

The time and space complexity of both functions MUST be at most polynomial in n, i.e. O(n**c) for some fixed c.  In particular, solutions that involving computing all n! permutations are NOT acceptable.  (Unofficial bonus points for O(n)).

Shortest solution (including both functions and any additional code) in each language wins.

### Examples

Assuming the two functions are f and g:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `f([0])` | `0` |
| `g(0,1)` | `[0]` |
|  |  |
| `f([0,1]), f([1,0])` | `0` and `1` in either order |
| `g(0,2), g(1,2)` | `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` in either order |
|  |  |
| `f([3,4,1,0,2])` | some integer in range 0,...,119 |
| `g(42,5)` | some permutation of 0,1,2,3,4 |
|  |  |
| `f(g(42,5))` | `42` |
| `g(f([3,4,1,0,2]),5)` | `[3,4,1,0,2]` |
|  |  |
| `f([1,0,1])` | not valid input (not a permutation) |
| `f([1,3,4])` | not valid input (not a permutation of 0,1,2) |
| `g(42,4)` | not valid input (42 >= 4!) |

### Notes

Permutations can be represented in any reasonable form.

You can assume that input(s) are valid (as described).

You can assume that n! fits in the standard integer type in your language, but your algorithm should theoretically work for any n.

Standard loopholes apply.

Answer (score 0):

Given matrix \$A\$ and \$A^n\$, work out any possible positive \$n\$.

Examples:

- \$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\3&2&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}36&32&44\\52&40&52\\12&8&12\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow 3\$
- \$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \text{any integer }\ge 3\$
- \$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \text{any odd positive integer }\$

## Sandbox Notes

- Since this question likely fall into pure matmul as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), will this be [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)?
- If so, what size and \$n\$ is reasonable?
- Should it multiply in a modulo-\$p\$ ring?
- If someone provide enough extra info, they have right to post this question(actually that's why I posted in sandbox)

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: Sometimes lots of different n can work. What should we output then?

Comment: @xnor "Any possible positive n". But I agree that it should be specified better.

Comment: @ophact It's edited later than comment

Answer (score 0):

## I am not a dad!

## Task

Given a non-empty string. Check if it starts with "I am"/"I'm" (case-insensitive) and if it is, output the dad joke. Otherwise, terminate
P.S. There must be nothing in the STDERR.

## Examples:

"I am an idiot" -> "Hi an idiot, I am Dad"
"I am rewuytheruty" -> "Hi rewuytheruty, I am Dad"
"i Am case insensitive" -> "Hi case insensitive, I am Dad"
"I'm A" -> "Hi A, I am Dad"
"i'M B" -> "Hi B, I am Dad"
"Iam together" -> terminated
"Nothing here!" -> terminated

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with shortest bytes wins.
- [These](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) loopholes are, obviously, forbidden.
- Standard code-golf rules apply.
- Please specify the language you are using and the amount of bytes.
- It would be great if you would put a link to a sandbox where your code can be ran in action, such as [TIO](https://tio.run).
- Explaining your code is very welcomed.

Comment: I don't think the exceptions add anything to this challenge to be honest. And if you do keep them, they need to be better specified.

Comment: Input validation is frowned upon (validation to check if any of the exceptions appear). As well as that, I observed that there are virtually no patterns or magic bitwise operations that can handle them, just hard-coding a few extra strings and some ternary operators. Doesn't really add anything to the other dad joke challenge to be honest.

Comment: And if I would remove the exceptions, will the challenge become better? Will it be worthy publishing?

Answer (score 0):

[Time till Friday](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230331/)

Comment: What time in Friday? 12am?

Comment: @Razetime Any time in Friday

Answer (score 0):

Write a shortest bijective program from String to Object.

You can specify two sets of chars \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$, both of which consist of at least 4 different chars<sup>[1]</sup>, and define:

- String: string consisting of only chars in \$C_1\$ `[C₁]*`
- Name: non-empty string consisting of only chars in \$C_2\$ `[C₂]+`
- Object: a finite map from Name to Object, such that every way to go down finally go to empty Object(empty map)

Reasonable I/O allowed. Outputting in `Object` in languages like JavaScript, Array/String with proper encoding, folder, shuld be fine.

## Notes

- [1] unary or binary is too easy.
- I meant to map to folder but folder charset is bad, then decided to give you choice.

## Sandbox Notes

- What does `proper encoding` mean? Or do I just remove the allowance?

Answer (score 0):

## Largest number with no repeating substrings of length \$l\$

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110490/74285), in turn inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1997084/909288).

When I read the above questions, I thought: "Cool". And then I thought "*What if we go further?*"

Therefore, in this challenge, you must find the largest number that has no repeating substrings of length n. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): fewest bytes wins.

## Meta Stuff

This seems insanely hard - is it well specified enough?

Any changes that seem reasonable to add?

Comment: I would recommend adding testcases and instead of linking to posts for people to read, you could clarify in the description.

Comment: Is this the same as [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23534/58974)?

Answer (score 0):

## Smallest number of panels to represent \$1\$ through \$n\$ in base \$b\$

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74478/74285). (I have taken a lot of inspiration from Puzzling recently).

Because not all of you spend all your (non-code-golf) time looking at puzzles, let me explain the relevant details.

The challenge involved figuring out how to express the numbers 1 through 8 in only 8 panels in bases 2, 3 and 4. Today, I want to do the converse.

Your task is to, given a number \$n\$ and a base, \$b\$, find the fewest number of panels to represent 1 - n in base b. By that, I mean taking a single continuous slice of the set of panels, we can represent a number, and we can do that for 1 through n.

To clarify, each panel can take a single base-\$b\$ number, and the goal is to find a way to represent each number from 1 through n as a base b number. A continuous slice is a set of panels such that all the panels are consecutive and in the same order as in the original number - for example, 221001120 - in which every two-digit and one-digit number is represented in reading order, left-to-right, as well as 100. Note that 101 and 111 are disallowed because they are not consecutive, with 0s in between, 110, 122 and 2110 are disallowed because they read from left to right, and 121 and 212 are disallowed because they reorder the panels.

For a bigger example, let us take the base as 3 and the number as 18: a valid solution is 122121110221010011200, as every number between 1 and 18 can be represented in base 3

1: **1**22121110221010011200

2: 1**2**2121110221010011200

3: 1221211**10**221010011200

4: 12212**11**10221010011200

5: 122**12**1110221010011200

6: 122121110221010011**20**0

7: 12**21**21110221010011200

8: 1**22**121110221010011200

9: 1221211102210**100**11200

10: 12212111022**101**0011200

11: 1221211**102**21010011200

12: 122121**110**221010011200

13: 12212**111**0221010011200

14: 1221211102210100**112**00

15: 12212111022101001**120**0

16: 122**121**110221010011200

17: **122**121110221010011200

18: 122121110221010011**200**

In order to verify your solution does work, provide an optimal answer by the number such that it can be checked.

Input looks like this: `n b`, and output like this: `number solution`.

Sample inputs and outputs to aid you (output is represented as o - yes I did work all of these out, and yes, I do believe it is the shortest to just find a place to append the number in):

\$b = 2\$:

```
n <= 8; o = n (11101000)
n = 9, 10; o = 11 (10011101000)
n = 11; o = 13 (1001011101000)
n = 12, 13, 14; o = 14 (11001011101000)
n = 15, 16; o = n (110010111010000)
```

\$b = 3\$:

```
n <= 9; o = n (221001120)
n = 10; o = 11 (22101001120)
n = 11; o = 13 (1022101001120)
n = 12; o = 14 (11022101001120)
n = 13, 14, 15; o = 15 (111022101001120)
n = 16; o = 17 (12111022101001120)
n = 17; o = 19 (12212111022101001120)
n = 18; o = 20 (122121110221010011200)
```

\$b = 4\$:

```
n <= 10; o = n (1101220213)
n = 11; o = 12 (231101220213)
n = 12, 13; o = 13 (231101220213)
n = 14, 15; o = n (33231101220213)
n = 16, 17; o = 18 (10033231101220213)
n = 18; o = 20 (1003323110122010213)
n = 19, 20; o = 22 (100103323110122010213)
```

(i'm not touching 5+ this took me an hour)

Answer (score 0):

## Iterated ultimatum [koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth)

Each round, players are paired. One player is the Proposer and the other is the Receiver.

The Proposer must choose a number x such that 0 < x < 100. The Receiver must then Accept or Reject this offer. If accepted, the Proposer gains x points  and the Receiver gains 100 - x points. If rejected, neither player gains anything. This is repeated several times, then the Proposer and Receiver roles are reversed, then new pairings are made.

Repeat.

The idea is that the Proposer must try to maximise his own gain, while the Receiver can try to coerce the Proposer to give a larger share of the 100 points by rejecting unfair offers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimatum_game

### Meta

- Too similar to Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma?
- Any other feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Solve [Encode a Lenguage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229994/) with score 0. Shortest code wins. Quine rule applies. I'll unlikely post it.

Comment: @pxeger Qunie rule.

Comment: Zsh, 120 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G/n@b/YVr3YNsbEXLUYSFgXFGXmlaQpqBQDUU16UWqBgq5bYUWaroKnmlp@Sk1NfoqCrmOejWdNSZGCbrKCga65goU6Wbr@/x8giwE "Zsh – Try It Online"). Can probably be quite a lot shorter

Comment: Undeleted as potential reference

Answer (score 0):

## Are these strings within N bit flips of each other? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given two strings `a` and `b`, and a positive integer `n`, determine if `b` can be reached by performing exactly `n` bit-flips on `a`.

A bit-flip is defined as changing one of the bits in the character encoding of a string from a 0 to a 1 or from a 1 to a 0

**The same bit may be flipped multiple times**, so the `0110` can be reached in exactly 2 bit-flips of itself, as well as in 0 (e.g. `0110 -> 0100 -> 0110`).

### Test-cases

##### Truthy

```
n   a         b
=======================
1   hello     hullo
3   hello     hullo
5   hello     hullo
69  hello     hullo
4   hello     hello
1   x         h
1   x         p
1   x         y
2   x         q
2   x         l
2   x         x
4   x         l
4   x         x
4   x         w
4   x         e
```

##### Falsey

```
n   a         b
=======================
2   hello     hullo
5   hello     hello
1   x         a
1   x         n
1   x         f
1   x         x
```

### Rules

- You may assume/require:

  - `n > 0`
  - `a` and `b` are the same length
  - neither string is empty
  - both strings consist only of lowercase letters `a` to `z` (or uppercase `A` to `Z` instead, if you wish)
- You should encode the strings in ASCII (or other ASCII-compatible encoding), but if your language cannot easily handle that, ask in the comments and I'll decide on special rules
- Your code does not need to handle high `n` or long `a` or `b`, but it must work in theory
- You may use [any reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

## Meta

- Better title suggestions?
- I limited to ASCII to avoid people finding loopholes that trivialise the challenge. Do you have any other suggestions that would work better?
- Test-case suggestions?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: This question is equals to: is n - (hamming distance of a and b) a non-negative even number?

Comment: @tsh yes, I've basically abandoned it

Answer (score 0):

## Maximum unique characters [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Write a program which maximises the amount of unique characters in its output while minimising the size of its source. The program must halt.

Functions for converting a character code to its character in any encoding are disallowed.

Your score is `output unique chars / size in bytes`, and higher is better.

### Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Should character code functions be banned?

Comment: Do you mean "output" instead of "input" in the first line? Also, it sounds like "shortest code to print all chars having Unicode codepoint from 0 to 1114111", which is pretty boring. And you can't ban "character code functions" since it is simply not a thing in lots of languages. And you can't get most of the characters without it besides hardcoding the string itself anyway (or eval-ing), which makes it even more boring.

Comment: Maybe don't ban "character code functions" as they are pretty much the only way to produce an interesting solution to this challenge.

Comment: @RecursiveCo. `for(let i=0;i<[insert 9's here];i++){console.log(String.fromCharCode(i)}` (in JS)
I'm just really bad at coming up with ideas. I've given up on this idea.

Comment: What's to stop me making up a character encoding where every possible sequence of bytes in the range 0x48 to 0x57 represents one of infinite "characters" and then outputting all decimal numbers? Boom, infinite score.

Answer (score 0):

## Extend the OEIS

On the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), there are a significant amount of sequences which do not have proper continuations to them, in other words, the length of the sequence was cut short by the methods at that point.

An example of this is the sequence in this [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51266/extending-oeis-counting-diamond-tilings/) before it was extended by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51662/99035) answer.

A sequence that wouldn't qualify for this post would be the [fibonacci](https://oeis.org/A000045) sequence because while it may have a limit on the OEIS, the end is not due to the method used, but instead due to the large amount of current entries.

##### Challenge:

Find a sequence on the OEIS that follows the above guidelines and extend it by any amount. Your answer should include the code, an explanation of it, as well as the new entries.

Example Answer

```
A1327807 
previous largest n=8 number = 100000001
new highest n=12 number = 37812879128

// code
// more code

// explanation of code and how you figured it out
```

Of course your answer doesn't need to follow that format exactly, it should just be close to it.

##### Notes:

You must write original code for this challenge. If there is already a program out there, and you're only contribution is running it on a better machine, that is a trivially extendable sequence.

This also goes for answers, as the only thing contributed cannot be simply better hardware.

This is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) for lack of a better tag, so good luck and have fun!

Comment: I think you should find one interesting sequence to extend (or some). Large part of this question is finding an extendable sequence that might be of interest (as popularity contest suggests). IMHO this part of research should be on asker's side.

Answer (score 0):

## Do I flip the side?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

#### Introduction

When writing on a piece of paper folded \$n\$ times you have \$2^{n+1}\$ sides available to write on. When writing on those sides, you can imagine the following sequence of actions (for \$n=2\$):

1. write on the first side and fill the whole side,
2. flip the paper to the next empty side and write there until filled,
3. now we have to unfold the paper once (at least) to get to the next empty side and "flip" the fold,
4. flip the paper to the next empty side,
5. unfold the paper twice to get to the empty side and "flip" the fold,
6. etc.

#### Challenge

Given number of folds \$n \geq 0 \$ output the number of unfolds needed to get to the next clear side.
Standard [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply, so you can:

- Take an index \$k \leq 2^{n+1}-1\$ and output the \$k^{th}\$ term, either 0 or 1 indexing.
- Take a positive integer \$k \leq 2^{n+1}-1\$ and output the first \$k\$ terms.
- Output whole sequence for given \$n\$.

#### Test cases

```
n | sequence
----------------------------------
0 | 0 (no unfolds, just a flip)
1 | 0 1 0
2 | 0 1 0 2 0 1 0
3 | 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0
4 | 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 4 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0
```

#### Meta

- Too easy?

Comment: Is this first \$2^{n+1}-1\$ items of https://oeis.org/A007814?

Comment: @tsh Yes, it is.

Comment: IMO this is a very near dupe of [ABACABA sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68978/78410).

Answer (score 0):

## Is this a valid Temtem character name?

Given a string of between 0 and 15 (inclusive) printable ASCII characters, determine whether the string represents an acceptable character name for the game Temtem.

The following rules apply to character names:

- Names must have at least 3 letters (a-z)
- Names may have up to 2 total prefixes and/or suffixes of at least one letter
- Prefixes and suffixes must be separated from the name by one of space, hyphen or apostrophe
- The first letter of the name and each prefix may be capitalised but all other letters must be lower case.

Truthy examples:

```
Daddy's girl
de Morgan
Rip Van Winkle
Spider-Man
X-Men
```

Falsy examples:

```
McDonald's
-XX-
'falsy'
```

Note: Temtem may apply other checks to character names not included here.

As this is [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), Output must be a single consistent value for all valid names. Output for invalid names must be consistent for a given invalid name, but may vary between different invalid names, so for instance a count of errors is an acceptable output format.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: Are `Rip Van winkle` and `spider-Man` valid?

Comment: @Adám They are for the purposes of this question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

## General Binary Counterman Jr

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229683/mr-binary-counterman)

General Binary Counterman Jr is the son of famed Mr. Binary Counterman. He’s continued in his father’s footsteps, counting strings of numbers in the family tradition. But binary has grown old; he’s not a computer. The General has waited for his father’s popularity to wane, and he has decided the time is nigh. The General is about to generalize!

As a reminder, his father would count the evens and odds like this:
`1 1 0 0 1 0`  would be read as  `1st odd, 2nd odd, 1st even, 2nd even, 3rd odd, 3rd even` and it becomes `1 3 0 2 5 4`.

But not so the General. Evens and odds are just 0s and 1s mod 2, the General knows this.  Instead of reducing mod 2, he likes to reduce strings down whatever mod he pleases. Once he does he counts the residues the same way as his father did, but in whatever mod he damn well wants.

The General has [read the algorithms that fans have sent his father](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229683/mr-binary-counterman). But he believes that his new method will yield sufficiently different strategies as to deserve its own page on the internet.

### Challenge

*Given two inputs representing a mod `m` and a list `L`, the nth occurrence of a given congruence class in the list should be output as the nth integer of that class.*

The I/O is very flexible and may take any reasonable format, so long as it doesn’t sidestep part of the problem. For instance, you may take the list backwards or as a string, but you can’t take it already reduced mod m.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least bytes wins!

[Reference Implementation](https://tio.run/%23%23XY9PSwMxEMXv8ykeKdJdWxZ1FXRhT56EHrxKKXRpUje4SZb8OfTTr5NQVMwlb@Y3700yX@LobLsIIejtjItLa4lJfylEhxT4GhVaL3Ea1RBzM8TBR5xcslHbT@zvDmBwNMctBik7ooIC@oxuzbXMYz3uifcsK7wPnqO1nVNEcDg7bzhDh7ItDEY1@HAJYXRpknYdIR0jHchsseOc4qzqJsyTjpXoRE2mtGNlasoT@6x1naOhGWDXhOj1XAmIHx/LAxGt8Oqk@v9u@rV2BD5eZahvTKlmnzdwb3P9IEu2baGs7HNymfrDsOH/L0vb4QktHvCMR1Yv3w)

### Example

In my examples, I will represent the I/O as `3: 5 3 2 8 4 5 9`  -> `1 3 2 4 5 6` to represent the reminder. This means `m = 2` and `L = 1 1 0 0 1 0`. But again, you are not required to do it this way. In fact, you’re encouraged to find the I/O scheme that works best for your language and algorithm!

**Input:** `3: 5 3 2 8 4 5 9`

This gets counted mod 3 by its congruence class of [0], [1] or [2]:

```
L  m       Count       
5 %3  ->  1st [2]  ->  2
3 %3  ->  1st [0]  ->  0
2 %3  ->  2nd [2]  ->  5
8 %3  ->  3rd [2]  ->  8
4 %3  ->  1st [1]  ->  1
5 %3  ->  4th [2]  ->  11
9 %3  ->  2nd [0]  ->  3
```

**Output:** `2 0 5 8 1 11 3`

### Test Cases

The most fun part! How do you like the test cases?

```
2: 1 3 0 2 5 4 
   1 3 0 2 5 4
```

```
2: 1 1 0 0 1 0
   1 3 0 2 5 4
```

```
5: 1 1 0 0 1 0
   1 6 0 5 11 10
```

```
1: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

```
100: 101 102 103 104 105
     1 2 3 4 5
```

```
10: 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9 7 9 3 2 3 8 4 6 2 6 4 3 3
    3 1 4 11 5 9 2 6 15 13 25 8 19 7 29 23 12 33 18 14 16 22 26 24 43 53
```

```
7: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
   3 6 2 5 1 4 0 10 13 9
```

```
8: 09 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 9 10
```

```
12: 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 110 121 132
    11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

```
11: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144
    1 12 2 3 5 8 13 10 23 0 34 45
```

```
4: 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048
   2 0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
```

### Other Cheats

In the interest of making this as flexible as possible for all the <s>masochistic and impossible</s> fun languages, here are other things you may skimp on:

- You may assume list `L`  will only contain single digit numbers.
- You may assume mod `m` will be a single digit number.
- You may do anything when `m = 0`, including throwing an error.
- You may assume no leading 0s in the numbers.
- It is less consistent with the pattern, but you may eliminate 0s from your output by starting the count for [0], and only the [0] class, at `m` instead. Then, in the example program, `1st [0] → 3` and `2nd [0] → 6`. It would output `2 *3* 5 8 1 11 *6*` instead of `2 *0* 5 8 1 11 *3*`
- Feel free to comment any other ideas and I will add them in if they don’t detract from the spirit of the challenge, and primarily serve to give the turing tarpits a hand. If the cheat would be used by mainstream and golfing langs, it’s probably not a good idea.

Please mention what cheats you’re taking advantage of, if any!

Answer (score 0):

## Find out what type of adjective it is

There are 3 types of adjectives: absolute, comparative, and superlative adjectives. Your program should print what type of adjective it is. The program is supposed to work on  finite lost of words.

### Notes

- Input will be a string, (not always 1 word), it'll be an adjective (the number of words will be finite)
- Output must be anything that represents absolute, comparative and superlative.
- The 15 adjectives below should be used as test cases and your program should be at least 90% accurate.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Test cases:

```
pushiest => superlative
homeliest => superlative
most miserly => superlative
outgoing => absolute
most feline => superlative
roasted => absolute
frightening => absolute
fairer => comparative
more uncomfortable => comparative
more classic => comparative
smarter => comparative
muffled => absolute
scratchier => comparative
meager => absolute
tartest => superlative
```

Comment: So it only needs to correctly identify 14 of the below 15?

Comment: @rak1507 at least. I'll add more test cases if necessary

Comment: @rak1507 but checking everyone of these won't work, as it's code golf

Comment: It should be made very clear whether the program is supposed to work on a finite list of words (as currently suggested) or on any input in theory. The approaches are going to be very different.

Comment: "tartest" is a superlative.

Comment: @DjinTonic okay done

Answer (score 0):

## [Packing Boxes into a Truck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231060/packing-cuboid-boxes-into-the-shortest-stretchy-truck)

Answer (score 0):

## [Project Euler 001 in constant time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230976/project-euler-1-multiples-in-constant-time)

Answer (score 0):

## Will the hydra finally die? Part II

#### Background

This is a follow up question to the question: [Will the Hydra finally die?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230778/will-the-hydra-finally-die/230992#230992)

As before a dangerous A Medusa have released a dangerous Hydra which is revived unless the exact number of heads it have is removed. The knights can remove a certain number of heads with each type of attack, and each attack causes a specific amount of heads to regrow. This time the knights are more impatient and having seen your previous abilities want you to** write a program or function that **returns a list of hits which will leave the hydra 1 hit from death**

<sup>Note that this is fundamentally different from [Become the Hydra Slayer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137980/become-the-hydra-slayer). in 2 aspects. 1: We are not asking for the optimal solution 2: each attack causes a *different* number of heads to grow back. this radically changes the approach needed.</sup>

*For example:*

```
input: heads = 2, 
       attacks = [1, 25, 62, 67], 
       growths = [15, 15, 34, 25], 

output: [5, 1, 0, 0]
```

*Explanation:* The Hydra has 10 heads to start with, we have 4 different `attacks` and for each attack, `growth` gives us the number of heads that grows back. `hits` gives us the number of times each attack is applied. So the number of heads the Hydra has after each attack is

```
2 -> 16 -> 30 -> 44 -> 58 -> 72 -> 62
```

Since `62` is a valid attack value (It lies in the attack list), we return `True` since the Hydra will die on the next attack (be left with 0 heads). Note that the order for when the attacks are done is irrelevant.

```
2 -> 16 -> 6 -> 20 -> 34 -> 48 -> 62
```

---

#### Input

Input should contain `heads` (an integer), `attacks` (a list of how many heads can be removed), `regrowths` (how many heads grow back per attack)

You may take input in any  [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). This includes, but is not limited to

- A list of tuples `(1, 15, 5), (25, 15, 1), (62, 34, 0), (67, 25, 0)`
- Lists `2, [1, 25, 62, 67], [15, 15, 34, 25], [5, 1, 0, 0]`
- Reading values from STDIN `1 15 1 15 1 15 1 15 1 15 25 15`
- A file of values

---

#### Output

- An array, or some way to easily indicate which hits the knights are to take. Example: `5 1 0 0`

**Note 1** Say that your input is `attacks = [1, 25, 62, 67]` and the hydra has 25 heads left, then you **cannot** output the answer as `[1,0,0,0]`, `[0,0,0,1]` etc. **Your output and input must be sorted similarly**. Otherwise it will be very confusing for the Knights.

**Note 2:** Your program can *never* leave the Hydra with a negative number of heads. Meaning if the Hydra has 15 heads, an attack removes 17 heads and regrows 38. You may not perform this attack.

---

#### Scoring

- This is a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) you will be scored as follows:
  the total sum of hits your code produces from the test data + length of answer in bytes
- Note that how you input and parse the test data is not part of your code length. Your code should, as stated above simply take in some a headcount, attacks, regrowth's and return a list/representation of how many hits each attack has to be performed to leave the hydra *exactly* 1 hit from death.

**Lowest score wins!**

---

#### Test data

```
       attacks = [1, 25, 62, 67], 
       growths = [15, 15, 34, 25],
```

**use every integer from `1` to `200` as the number of heads.** An sample from the first 100 can be found below. Again your program does not have to return these values, it is merely an example of how the scoring would work. As seen below the total sum for each of these hits are `535` meaning my score would be `535+length of code in bytes`

```
   1 [0, 0, 0, 0]
   2 [5, 1, 0, 0]
   3 [3, 2, 0, 0]
   4 [7, 4, 0, 0]
   5 [5, 5, 0, 0]
   6 [4, 0, 0, 0]
   7 [2, 1, 0, 0]
   8 [6, 3, 0, 0]
   9 [4, 4, 0, 0]
  10 [8, 6, 0, 0]
  11 [1, 0, 0, 0]
  12 [5, 2, 0, 0]
  13 [3, 3, 0, 0]
  14 [7, 5, 0, 0]
  15 [5, 6, 0, 0]
  16 [4, 1, 0, 0]
  17 [2, 2, 0, 0]
  18 [6, 4, 0, 0]
  19 [4, 5, 0, 0]
  20 [3, 0, 0, 0]
  21 [1, 1, 0, 0]
  22 [5, 3, 0, 0]
  23 [3, 4, 0, 0]
  24 [7, 6, 0, 0]
  25 [0, 0, 0, 0]
  26 [4, 2, 0, 0]
  27 [2, 3, 0, 0]
  28 [6, 5, 0, 0]
  29 [4, 6, 0, 0]
  30 [3, 1, 0, 0]
  31 [1, 2, 0, 0]
  32 [5, 4, 0, 0]
  33 [3, 5, 0, 0]
  34 [2, 0, 0, 0]
  35 [0, 1, 0, 0]
  36 [4, 3, 0, 0]
  37 [2, 4, 0, 0]
  38 [6, 6, 0, 0]
  39 [2, 0, 0, 0]
  40 [3, 2, 0, 0]
  41 [1, 3, 0, 0]
  42 [5, 5, 0, 0]
  43 [3, 6, 0, 0]
  44 [2, 1, 0, 0]
  45 [0, 2, 0, 0]
  46 [4, 4, 0, 0]
  47 [2, 5, 0, 0]
  48 [1, 0, 0, 0]
  49 [2, 1, 0, 0]
  50 [3, 3, 0, 0]
  51 [1, 4, 0, 0]
  52 [5, 6, 0, 0]
  53 [1, 0, 0, 0]
  54 [2, 2, 0, 0]
  55 [0, 3, 0, 0]
  56 [4, 5, 0, 0]
  57 [2, 6, 0, 0]
  58 [1, 1, 0, 0]
  59 [2, 2, 0, 0]
  60 [3, 4, 0, 0]
  61 [1, 5, 0, 0]
  62 [0, 0, 0, 0]
  63 [1, 1, 0, 0]
  64 [2, 3, 0, 0]
  65 [0, 4, 0, 0]
  66 [4, 6, 0, 0]
  67 [0, 0, 0, 0]
  68 [1, 2, 0, 0]
  69 [2, 3, 0, 0]
  70 [3, 5, 0, 0]
  71 [1, 6, 0, 0]
  72 [0, 1, 0, 0]
  73 [1, 2, 0, 0]
  74 [2, 4, 0, 0]
  75 [0, 5, 0, 0]
  76 [1, 0, 1, 0]
  77 [0, 1, 0, 0]
  78 [1, 3, 0, 0]
  79 [2, 4, 0, 0]
  80 [3, 6, 0, 0]
  81 [1, 0, 1, 0]
  82 [0, 2, 0, 0]
  83 [1, 3, 0, 0]
  84 [2, 5, 0, 0]
  85 [0, 6, 0, 0]
  86 [1, 1, 1, 0]
  87 [0, 2, 0, 0]
  88 [1, 4, 0, 0]
  89 [2, 5, 0, 0]
  90 [0, 0, 1, 0]
  91 [1, 1, 1, 0]
  92 [0, 3, 0, 0]
  93 [1, 4, 0, 0]
  94 [2, 6, 0, 0]
  95 [0, 0, 1, 0]
  96 [1, 2, 1, 0]
  97 [0, 3, 0, 0]
  98 [1, 5, 0, 0]
  99 [2, 6, 0, 0]
 100 [0, 1, 1, 0]
535
```

## Meta

- What would a good scoring method for this type of question be?
- My method outputs `2873` for the total count from 1 to 200, is this too high, too low?
- Feel free to suggest other improvements to my testing data

Answer (score 0):

### Transdeletion

Transdeletion is the process of removing a letter from a word and forming another word by creating an anagram from the remaining letters.

If you can do this repeatedly, all the way down to a single letter ("A" or "I", usually, in English), you have formed a "[Transdeletion Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdeletion_pyramid)".

**The Challenge**

Given a word list (containing any number of words, up to the max your language can handle) and a starting word, find and output the Transdeletion pyramid.

The word list will include the starting word, and is guaranteed to contain all of the words required to make the pyramid *(Sandbox: should it? Or is it a better challenge if it won't always be possible to succeed?)*. A change of case for any letters of the word is allowed at any time - i.e. dealing with casing isn't part of the challenge. So you can assume all inputs are in lowercase, or uppercase, or whatever suits.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins, usual rules apply.

**Examples**

In the form `[[wordList],"startWord"] -> [ordered output list]`

```
[["a", "an", "ant"], "ant"] -> ["ant","an","a"]
[["I", "in", "tin", "sink", "ink"], "sink"] -> ["sink","ink","in", "I"]
[["I", "in", "tin", "sink", "ink"], "in"] -> ["in", "I"]
[["a", "I", "tin", "ant", "sink", "an" "ink"], "ant"] -> ["ant","an","a"]
[["FAT", "TALIERA", "INTERLAMINATES", "ULCER", "ALTER", "TALE", "A", "RATE", "I", "ANTICEREMONIALIST", "MATERIAL", "INCOMPETENT", "TRILAMINATE", "TEA", "TEA", "TRIFLE", "NONMATERIALITIES", "FRATERNISATION", "AT", "AT", "ORNAMENTALITIES", "RETAIL", "TAIL", "MATERNALITIES", "TERMINALIA", "LATIMERIA", "FATIMA", "OBSCURE", "LENS", "MATRILINEATE"],"ANTICEREMONIALIST"] -> ["ANTICEREMONIALIST", "NONMATERIALITIES", "ORNAMENTALITIES", "INTERLAMINATES", "MATERNALITIES", "MATRILINEATE", "TRILAMINATE", "TERMINALIA", "LATIMERIA", "MATERIAL", "TALIERA", "RETAIL", "ALTER", "RATE", "TEA", "AT", "A"]
```

**Sandbox Questions**

1. Should it be possible that the input contains no valid chains?
2. Should the challenge instead be to find the longest chain, even if it doesn't go down to 1 letter?
3. Should the starting word be provided or would it be a better challenge without it?

Answer (score 0):

## Decide Magma's Identity

### Objective

Given a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) with 256 elements, decide whether it has *the* identity element.

### Definition

A **magma** is a set endowed with a binary operation. Let's denote the set by \$S\$ and the binary operation by \$\circ\$.

An element \$e \in S\$ is *the* **identity element** if for every \$a \in S\$, \$e \circ a = a \circ e = a\$ holds.

If \$e\$ exists, its existence is unique, for if \$f \in S\$ also is an identity element, \$e = e \circ f = f\$.

### Input Format

The binary operation \$\circ\$ itself, as a black-box function, will be inputted.

The type of \$\circ\$ doesn't matter. Possible choices include (type names in C):

- Accepting two `char`s, returning one `char`
- Accepting two `int8_t`s, returning one `int8_t`
- Accepting two `uint8_t`s, returning one `uint8_t`
- Accepting one `int16_t` (to break bytewise), returning one `unsigned char`

### Ungolfed Solution

#### Haskell

This implementation is much generalized version of the challenge. It can test an arbitrary finite magma, and will explicitly find the identity element if it exists.

It might seem to have time complexity of \$O(n^2)\$, but it's actually \$O(n)\$.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

findIdentity :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => (a -> a -> a) -> Maybe a
findIdentity op = listToMaybe $ do
    let elements = [minBound .. maxBound]
    e <- elements
    guard (all (\f -> op e f == f) elements)
    guard (all (\f -> op f e == f) elements)
    pure e
```

Answer (score 0):

## Compile Esolang to Esolang

Based on [Convert FRACTRAN to Brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/convert-fractran-into-brainfuck).

- Compile Brainfuck to FRACTRAN
- Compile /// to Brainfuck
- Compile Brainfuck to ///

If you have other ideas, please add them. Be sure it's reasonably doable with simple tarpits, eg Jelly to Vyxal to APL isn't all that fun. If you *can* make a variation of that fun, that should be posted separately.

If you'd like me to make this into a CW to make it easier to contribute, please comment and let me know!

Comment: FRACTRAN to Retina 0.8.2 would prove that the latter is Turing-complete (Regex on its own isn't, but Retina has loops. On the other hand, Retina 1 has eval, so you can probably do some nasty things like a payload-capable quine attempting to evaluate itself, thus implementing Fibonacci recursively.)

Comment: @Neil I'm thinking that one of them should be a simple, well-known and pretty vanilla lang. Eg Brainfuck <-> Retina, or, since it's based on string subs, /// <-> Retina might be fun. How do those sound? Or would you prefer from FRACTRAN/another Minsky machine? I also am slightly worried about Retina's complexity, but maybe just a subset of Retina would be required?

Comment: I can't comment on the other languages because I don't know them, but Retina 0.8.2 isn't that complex; its only loop is the convergence loop and the only conditional code is basically whether a regex matches or not.

Comment: is this structured as an answer chaining problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Make me some puzzles

So, a while ago on Puzzling, I posted [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109687/please-check-my-math-homework). It basically had a whole bunch of equations that were wrong, and when you figured out how much they were wrong by, and transformed 1-26 into A-z, it yielded the phrase ALLWRONG.

Your challenge is to take a string of letters as input, and output a series of *wrong*, randomly generated equations that are wrong by the correct amount to yield  said string.

Equations must be of the form `number operation number = number`, where each number is a positive integer less than 100, and the operators are `+-*/`, although × and ÷ are acceptable instead of `*/`.

I'm going to be quite lenient on the definition of 'random' in this one - all possible equations must have a nonzero chance of appearing for any given letter.

Valid equations should have the result of the left hand side's difference from the right hand side being the correct number to, when 1-26 is transformed into A-Z, yield the corresponding character.

Output can be as an array, newline separated, whatever. Equations don't need to be spaced, that's just for readability. You can even output as a list of `[1,+,1,=,3]` or something.

## Testcases

These are *possible*  outputs, not proper testcases.

```
A => 1 + 1 = 3
HI => 3 * 4 = 4, 9 * 2 = 9
LOL => 20 / 5 = 16, 7 * 5 = 20, 50 - 23 = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid traps, run to an exit! [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

### Code layout

Your code shall have:

- One kind of characters as the **protagonist**. The protagonist must appear exactly once in the source.
- One other kind as the **trap**. Traps must appear once or more.
- One other kind as the **exit**. Exits must appear once or more.

No other restrictions.

### Objective

The protagonist can **move** by replacing another character by the protagonist and removing the original protagonist.

Write a program/function that:

- Outputs zero when executed/invoked on its own.
- Outputs a negative number if the protagonist moved into a trap. The output need not be consistent.
- Outputs a positive number if the protagonist moved into an exit. The output need not be consistent.
- All other modifications fall in *don't care* situation.

### Example

Given the following source:

```
Hello, world!
```

where `H` is the protagonist, `l`s are traps, and `o`s are exits, the source shall output zero.

Then the following sources shall output a negative number:

```
eHlo, world!

elHo, world!

ello, worHd!
```

And the following sources shall output a positive number:

```
ellH, world!

ello, wHrld!
```

### Scoring

The source with the least number of **characters** (not bytes) shall win.

Answer (score 0):



Answer (score 0):

## Is it a mathy-county-number

So I recently reinvented some boring type of number.
Reinvented because I'm sure somebody else invented it before, but 'till figure out who invented it, let's call these numbers **mathy-county-numbers**.

### So what is a mathy-county-number?

A mathy-county-number number is a number whose count of each digit also appears in the number.
It's a number like 332222410.
The number 3 occurs 2 times, so there must be a 2. The number 2 occurs 4 times, so there must be a 4. 4 occurs once, and some other numbers occur 0 times.

The task is simple: Write a program to check if a number (received by the input) is a mathy-county-number.

### Rules

- Default loopholes apply
- Default I/O rules apply
- Output must be a truthy or falsy value
- No digit will appear more than 9 times

### Examples

```
332222410
> True

33222241
> False

1
> False

33222
> False

1122233334444455555566666667777777788888888890
> True

112223333444445555556666666777777778888888889
> True

122334444456789
> False
```

Comment: "The number 3 occurs 2 times, so there must be a 2." Does this means "3312" is valid as there is a 2 (although not followed by 3).

Comment: Why "1" is falsy?

Comment: @tsh 1: no, because  in 3312 there's no 0. but eg. 03312 would be valid

Comment: @tsh 2: 0 is not there, 9, 8, 7, ... occur 0 times

Comment: "If any digit occurs more than 9 times, count it as a 9." is needlessly complicated, I'd suggest just saying that no digit will appear more than 9 times. The output for the last 2 test cases in unclear - what is `sdcvbhnjmk` supposed to represent? Just use something like `true/false`. Additionally, why is `33222` true? By the same logic as the example, it contains "some other numbers zero times", so should include a `0` to be true, right?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks, don't know why I'm addressing the changes now

Comment: If 0 does not occur in a number, does that mean that some number appears 0 times?

Comment: 0 has to occur in a mathy-county-number if some number appears 0 times.
Example 112 would be invalid because eg. 3 appears 0 times. 1120 would be valid though.

Comment: @thejonymyster ^

Comment: in the number 123456789, 0 appears 0 times. However, there is no 0 in the number to account for the fact that there is 0 of that number. Should this output truthy or falsy? (Note: this is a paradox)

Comment: Also, you should clearly define what makes a number mathy-county, rather than having the user rely on an example. (Not that it isn't easy to figure out, but it's good practice and leads to no assumptions being made, especially ones you weren't prepared for)

Comment: @thejonymyster I'd say the number itself should be falsy because there is no 0. However even if you add a 0 it'll stay falsy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that in

Comment: @mathcat so any number without a 0 in it should return falsy. Also, numbers with leading 0s being counted differently is strange. How is 01 different from 1, numerically?

Answer (score 0):

## [Group binary shapes together](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231864/group-binary-shapes-together)

Comment: I only asked about input, though you could allow it for output too, by allowing each group's 1s to be replaced with consecutive numbers (1-indexed, of course).

Comment: @Adám I don't think I'll allow it for output, that seems like too significant a deviation from the original challenge

Comment: Sure, makes sense, and I didn't think of it before you mentioned it :-)

Comment: Can we answer with a list of lists of indices into the input? E.g. `[[1,3],[2],[4,5]]`?

Comment: @Adám Yes, added

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]` and `[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]`

Comment: Please supply test cases as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

## Two inverse quines

Your challenge is to write two programs A and B such that:

- A outputs B
- B outputs A
- Wherever there is a space character in A, there is a non-whitespace character in B, and vice versa (newlines must be consistent through both)
- This means A and B are the same length in characters.

For example `A`  and  `B` are valid, but `A`  and   `B` are not.

Newlines must be consistent through both, so `A \nB`  and  `C\n D` are valid, but `A   C` and `B\nD` are not.

## Scoring

Your score is the length in bytes of either of your programs. If they're different lengths in *bytes*, take the average.

Answer (score 0):

**The Roly-Poly, Square-Wheeled Quine**

Moved [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/232942/the-roly-poly-square-wheeled-quine). Thank you for the comments.

Comment: I feel like the whitespace rule is not really necessary, except for maybe just newlines? If my code is just whitespace does that mean I just have to output 6 newlines?

Comment: I'm not following how you are using "is". Do you mean if  your code *contains* whitespace?  Or do I need to specify some minimum n? Thanks.

Comment: For example, the language Whitespace is composed of only three whitespace characters. What should that be outputting?

Comment: Wouldn't a minimum n x n  square of non-blank characters take care of that? Non-whitespace characters that generate whitespace are fine.

Comment: I looked Whitespace up. I don't think it can play if its output is encoded as whitespace between characters. Goodness, is it that popular?

Comment: The output for Whitespace isn't encoded in any special way. A minimum of n being 1 would solve some problems sure, but my initial complaint is that I don't see why spaces should be treated any different from any other character. Newlines make sense sure, but not spaces or tabs (though this still leads to an issue with Unary). On the other hand, the scoring mechanism is still bytes, so I guess it isn't really abusable

Comment: Esthetically I like the idea of code output resembling a car leaving a car compactor. I see the code being on any number of lines desired as long as output is squares.

Answer (score 0):

## Knapsack Paragraph, Format For A Phone

There are several paragraph formatting questions already on the site, where a string of text is split on space or other boundaries in order to fit into a rectangle; but they usually involve specifying a particular width for the formatted paragraph in addition to the supplied text.

For this problem, instead of a fixed width, we want to minimize the *perimeter* of the bounding box of the formatted text. Because we are developers for a phone app and we have to pay for the border by the inch. Or some other such tom-foolery; actually I noticed that this is a bit of a knapsack problem, and I just like the resemblance to that old folk song "knick-knack paddywack, give a dog a bone".

### Challenge

Define a *layout* of a string **T** of text as a list of **n** strings **s[i]** such that the joined string using spaces as delimiter, i.e. **s[0]+' '+s[1]+' '+...+' '+s[n-1]** is equal to **T**.

The *semiperimeter* of a layout **s** is **n** plus the maximum length of any **s[i]** in **s**.

Given as input a string **T**, your submission must output the minimum semiperimeter across all valid layouts of **T**. Alternatively, you may output a layout which has a semiperimeter which is minimal.

The restrictions on input are forgiving; in particular, you may take **T** as a list of words (strings without spaces) instead of a single string; so long as the result includes the count of spaces that *would* be present in the layout when calculating the semiperimeter.

This is code-golf; so the shortest submission in each language is the winner, and will be honored with a parade at some vague time in the near future.

### Notes:

Just wanted to get this down; will edit later. Mulling whether to have output be the integer, or an example layout having the minimal perimeter. The former is simpler to construct; but the latter just seems more satisfying as an output.

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is to write a method that compresses/decompresses strings. It will get two arguments: any string (with any ASCII characters) to compress/decompress, and a boolean. If the boolean is true, compress, else decompress.

It can either print the output to stdout or return the data.

The twist is that your score is equal to the byte count of your source code + the byte count of your source code *compressed by the compressor*. So if your code was `c=>c` (which is invalid btw), your score would be 4 + 4 = 8.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes not allowed
- The decompression and compression should work.
- Your code should not just return the same data. So this

  ```js
  c=>c
  ```

  is invalid

### Test function to check the score

If you like, here's a function which checks your (`javascript`) answer.

```js
function checkCompressor(compressor) {
    const source = compressor.toString();
    const compressed = compressor(source, true);
    const decompressed = compressor(compressed, false);
    if (source !== decompressed) return false;
    return compressed; // Have to get byte count manually
}
```

Comment: What are the possible input ranges for the compressor and the decompressor? Is it allowed for a compressor to output something longer than the input for some inputs? Under the current rules, it looks like I can get a score of 0 by doing `if input == itself, return empty string; otherwise do something else`.

Comment: @Bubbler nice catch! I've updated the question a bit, to account for these cases

Comment: "any characters" doesn't look objective to me. Does it include full Unicode range, or just ASCII or Latin-1, for example? Is the length of the compression measured in characters or bytes?

Comment: @Bubbler Any characters were supposed to mean any and all characters, but I think that's a bit too much, so i'm changing it to ascii for now. The length of compression is measured in bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Reverse cadaddadadaddddaddddddr

The Lisp language has a family of functions `car`, `cdr`, `cadr`, etc for accessing arrays. For each one, an `a` defines taking the first item of an array, and a `d` defines taking the rest.

For example, running `cadr` on `[[1,3,4],5,7]` will return `[3,4]` as the `a` gets the first item (`[1,3,4]`) and the `d` removes the first item.

We've already had a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/cadaddadadaddddaddddddr-linked-list-accessing) regarding running a `cadaddadadaddddaddddddr` on a list, but what about the reverse?

Your challenge is to, given a string of the type above (starting with a `c`, ending with a `r`, with only `ad` in the middle), and a single value, create an array such that running the string as a `cadaddadadaddddaddddddr` on the array returns said value.

For example, given the input `cadar, 1` a possible output could be `[[0,[1]]]` since running `cadar` on that gives 1.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

These are possible outputs, all that matters is that your program  returns an array which works for the condition.

```
car, 3 => [3]
cdddar, 5 => [0,0,0,5]
cadadadadar, 4 => [[0,[0,[0,[0,[4]]]]]]
caaaaaaaaar, 2 => [[[[[[[[[[2]]]]]]]]]]
```

Let me know if any of these are wrong.

Comment: one "]" is missing at the end in the 3rd and 4th test, if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @Basto Ok, thanks!

Comment: "only `ad` in the middle" ~> "only `a`, `d` in the middle"? Else I would read it as matching `/c(ad)*r/`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech This is abandoned, feel free to take  it up if you want.

Comment: Ok. I would have liked to solve it. Thanks for the offer to take it up but I respectfully decline.

Comment: @JonathanFrech [I posted it, but I made several mistakes that no one realised until it was too late](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233405/reverse-cadaddadadaddddaddddddr).

Comment: But with some polish it would be a good question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

## Determine the length of a Puyo Puyo chain

Puyo Puyo is a Japanese tile-matching puzzle game currently developed by Sega. The gameplay seems simple but it is actually quite complex.

You have a 12x6 board which you can fill with various colors (typically red, green, blue, yellow, and purple) of Puyo (round slime-like creatures with eyes). Each turn, you control a pair of Puyo that you can manipulate and place on the board not unlike Tetris.

When a pair is placed, gravity is applied to the board. If there is an empty gap underneath one or more Puyo in a column, they fall to fill the gap.

When two Puyo of the same color are adjacent to each other, they link together. When 4 or more Puyo are linked, they pop (disappear). After a group of Puyo pops, if gravity causes another group to pop, then you have created a chain. The goal of Puyo Puyo is to place Puyo so that you create as long of a chain as possible to overwhelm your opponent with nuisance Puyo.

Nuisance Puyo are a special case - they are colorless (usually gray or transparent), but more importantly they do not link together. Instead, they pop when an adjacent colored Puyo pops.

### Challenge

Given a Puyo Puyo board in any reasonable format (12 lines of 6 character strings, a 12x6 matrix of characters/numbers, 12 6-character strings in an array, etc.) output the chain length as a number. Standard loopholes apply.

This is code-golf, so shortest source code wins.

Bonus: In Puyo Puyo Tsuu, a hidden 13th row was added above the playfield to allow for longer chains. You will get a -5% score bonus if your program can optionally accept a 13th row.

### Test cases

**Note:** Intermediate board states are shown to demonstrate the game mechanics; you are not required to output them.

Key: **R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue, **Y**ellow, **P**urple, **N**uisance, **.** empty

Output: `4`

```
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
......>......>......>......>......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
..GBR. ...BR. ....R. ...... ......
..RGBR ...GBR ....BR .....R ......
..RGBR ...GBR ....BR .....R ......
.RRGBR ..GGBR ...BBR ....RR ......
```

Output: `4`

```
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ...... ......
......>......>......>......>......
.G.... ...... ...... ...... ......
YG.... ...... ...... ...... ......
NGY... ..Y... ..Y... ...... ......
NGR... Y.R... ..R... ..Y... ......
YBR... YBR... ..R... ..R... ......
YYBR.. YYBR.. .BBR.. ..RR.. ......
BBRR.. BBRR.. BBRR.. ..RR.. ..Y...
```

Output: `0`

```
......
......
......
......
......
......
......
......
.B....
BR....
BR....
BR....
```

Output: `19` (requires bonus; sorry, no intermediate states)

```
..YRYY
GBBYRG
RBYRYY
GBYRYG
RYRGBG
YRGBYG
RYRGBY
RYRGBY
RGGBGB
GBYRBB
RGBYRG
RGBYRG
RGBYRG
```

The [Puyo Nexus chain simulator](https://puyonexus.com/chainsim/?w=6&h=12&chain=6466755647456466756467464757647567464756464756477575756455475647475647475647) might be useful while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

## Convince me that this vector theorem is true

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)

#### Background Information

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition):

> A sequence of vectors \$\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_3,\dots,\mathbf v_k\$ from a vector space \$V\$ is said to be *linearly dependent*, if there exists scalars \$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k\$ such that:
> $$a_1\mathbf v_1+a_2\mathbf v_2+\cdots+a_k\mathbf v_k=\mathbf 0$$
> where \$\mathbf 0\$ denotes the zero vector.

Based on many sources<sup>1</sup> around the internet, it is true that

> If there are more vectors than dimensions, the vectors are linearly dependent.

In other words, if the vector space is \$\mathbb R^n\$(the number of entries in each vector is \$n\$), then the sequence of vectors \$\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_p\$ is always linearly dependent if \$p>n\ge2\$.

#### Task

After looking around, I'm still not entirely convinced that the above statement is true. Please convince me with a program that takes in: the dimension \$n\$(you don't have to take this in if you don't need to), and \$p\$ \$n\$-dimensional vectors \$\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_p\$, where \$p>n\ge2\$. You can take in \$p\$ in your program if you want to. You can assume that all vector entries in each vector are integer values. The input format can be whatever you choose, as long as there is a clear distinction between each vector. The program should return a list of scalars \$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p\$, with at least one of them non-zero, such that
$$a_1\mathbf v_1+a_2\mathbf v_2+\cdots+a_p\mathbf v_p=\mathbf 0$$
to show linear dependency. If there are multiple outputs that work, you can output any one of them. The output format is also flexible, as long as it is clear what the values of each scalar are.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

#### Example I/O

Input:

\$n=2\$

\$p=3\$

\$\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_p=\pmatrix{4\\5},\pmatrix{8\\10},\pmatrix{6\\7}\$

Output:

One possible solution is \$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p=2,-1,0\$. We can quickly test that this does work:
$$2\pmatrix{4\\5}+(-1)\pmatrix{8\\10}+0\pmatrix{6\\7}=\pmatrix{8\\10}-\pmatrix{8\\10}+\pmatrix{0\\0}=\pmatrix{0\\0}=\mathbf 0$$

#### Test Cases:

Work in progress

```
n, vectors -> scalars
2, [(4,5),(8,10),(6,7)] -> [2,-1,0]
2, [(3,6),(6,7),(3,9),(2,4),(5,5)] -> [2,0,0,-3,0]
3, [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6),(5,6,7),(6,7,8),(7,8,9),(8,9,10)] -> [1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Some sources: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#More_vectors_than_dimensions), [this](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ejiwenhe/math2331/lectures/sec1_7.pdf#page=13), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473853/prove-that-n1-vectors-in-mathbbrn-cannot-be-linearly-independent), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301871/prove-that-if-we-have-more-vectors-than-rows-in-a-single-vector-then-they-are-l)

---

## Concerns

- Has a similar challenge been done before?
- Is it clear what the challenge is specifying?
- I want to change the title to be more specific, but I'm not sure what to change it to.
- I need some test cases, but I'm not sure what test cases would be good for this.

Comment: A possible title would be "Solve a linear equation system" or "Find a kernel vector"

Comment: "\$n\geq 2\$" is superfluous.

Comment: I do not quite understand the premise, since a vector space's dimension is defined to be its basis' length. Thus if you are not convinced your statement is true you should not accept \$K^n\$ to have dimension \$n\$.

Answer (score 0):

## All valid N * N Flow Free Boards.

Since there are several other Flow Free question, either here or on main, but none, as far as I can tell, that do this, I will ask the question some of us have pondered at night: How many valid Flow Free Boards are there?

## What is a valid board?

From what I can tell from my attempts at time trial, a valid board has all of these:

1. Has between floor(2N/3) and ceil(3N/2) flows (where a flow is two distinct points, defined as it's ends, between which a line can be drawn connecting them).
2. No two endpoints of a flow can be adjacent.
3. The board must be solvable - that is, there must be a way that all endpoints of the flows can be connected together such that every square of the board is filled once and only once, and no two paths intersect at all.

## Input/Output

Your program will receive N, the side length of the board. The board will always be square (as that is the case in most boards), and it must return all valid boards, and the number of such boards.

As always, you can take input and output in any reasonable format, and shortest byte count wins!

## Meta

Has this been done before?

Anything that needs specifying?

Answer (score 0):

**Who Won Tic-Tac-Toe?**

Your job is to be the judge of a game of Tic-Tac-Toe.

Given an input consisting of three lines (9 characters not including newlines), determine the winner of the game of Tic-Tac-Toe.

For example, for the input

```
XOO
-XO
O-X
```

your program should either return or print `X`.

For tie games or games where no one has won, do not print or return anything.

The only input characters will be 'X', 'O', and '-' (along with two newlines), and the only outputs your program should give are 'X' and 'O' (or nothing).

Also note that the given board will be a valid game of Tic-Tac-Toe, so there will be no situations where both players have winning positions.

More examples:

```
OOO
---
---
```

=> `O`

```
OXO
--X
---
```

=> `(nothing)`

```
OXO
X-O
X-O
```

=> `O`

```
OXO
XOX
XOX
```

=> `(nothing)`

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144116/tic-tac-toe-x-or-o

Answer (score 0):

## [Implement the LC-3 VM [1] using 16-bit subneg4 [2] only & test it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233581/66833)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and thank you for using the Sandbox! We require challenges to be self-contained; you should fully explain the terms/acronyms used, as well as anything else relevant to the challenge - in short, imagine you're explaining this to someone who knows nothing about it. I'd also suggest removing the time limit, and explain the winning criteria better

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! The scoring criteria are kinda confusing for people who are new to such system, you may want to add some scoring examples because it's very unique compare to ordinary code-golf.

Answer (score 0):

## Tic-Tac Clock

given a time of the day (0-12 inclusive) output the closest fitting clock. This means `0/12`, `3`, `6` and `9` should be straight up/to the side. The one's in between go in the corners!

The clock should look as follows:

```
      #|#
0  -> #+#
      ###

      ##/
1  -> #+#
      ###

      ##/
2  -> #+#
      ###

      ###
3  -> #+-
      ###

      ###
4  -> #+#
      ##\

      ###
5  -> #+#
      ##\

      ###
6  -> #+#
      #|#

      ###
7  -> #+#
      /##

      ###
8  -> #+#
      /##

      ###
9  -> -+#
      ###

      \##
10 -> #+#
      ###

      \##
11 -> #+#
      ###

      #|#
12 -> #+#
      ###
```

This is code-golf so the shortest answer (per language) in bytes wins.

### questions

This is my first question so I'd appreciate some feedback,
mainly if this challenge would be too tedious to do.

Comment: Given that the input is limited to `1` through `12`, I'd suggest just showing what each output should be for all the possible inputs, just to avoid any confusion

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Will edit it. Do you think this would be good to post on the main site otherwise?

Comment: Overall, looks good (though I haven't done any dupe searching). One thing I'd clarify a bit would be the output format - can it be any characters, or does it have to match as shown? Can the output be a list of lines, or does it have to be a multi line string? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 numbers using a graphics card

## Introduction

Graphics cards have great performance when doing big calculations. So lets make a small calculation

## Challenge

- Inputs: 2 floats of choice
- output: the addition of the two floats.
- The addition should be calculated on the graphics card, but it doesn't matter if it doesn't work on all gpu's
- Lowest score in bytes wins

## Example Input and Output

2.5 and 3.2 -> 5.7

Answer (score 0):

## What will the radio play next week?

Each week, Billboard publishes the US music industry standard ranking of the 100 most popular songs based on sales, radio play, and online streaming. [The current chart can be found here.](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100)

For each song on the chart, Billboard reports the song's current ranking (from 1 to 100, with 1 being the best), the previous week's ranking of that song (labeled "last week"), the best ranking that the song has ever received by Billboard (labeled "peak"), and the number of weeks that the song has appeared on Billboard charts to date (labeled "wks on chart").

Pop stations in the US generally play the top 40 most popular songs on a given week. In this challenge, we will predict what the radio will play next week given previous Billboard charts.

### The Data

[This text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyyeahrc16ph01b/lastweek.txt?dl=0) provides the "last week" data for every chart from July 25, 2015 though July 17, 2021 (based on data provided [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dhruvildave/billboard-the-hot-100-songs)). There are 313 lines (one for each week) with 100 comma-separated numbers in each line. The first line corresponds to July 25, 2015, and [on that week's chart](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2015-07-24), "Cheerleader" by OMI was ranked #1 (up from #2 the previous week), while Chris Young's "I'm Comin' Over" made its debut on the chart at #100. In the first line of the data provided, this is reflected with the first entry being `2` and the last entry being `101` (throughout, `101` indicates that the song did not chart on the previous week). The next line of the data starts with a `1`, indicating that OMI's "Cheerleader" was still ranked #1 on [the August 1, 2015 chart](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2015-08-01). In this way, the data captures how songs move up and down the chart from week to week.

### The Challenge

Write a program or function that, for each `n` from `0` to `312`, receives the first `n` lines of the data as input and outputs **the first 40 numbers** from line `n+1`.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

Answer (score 0):

## [Implement a tag system simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235279/implement-a-tag-system-simulator)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple Averages

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

In math, the average or mean of a range of numbers is in the middle of all of the numbers. The farthest number in the range from the average is as close as possible to it. So, to find multiple averages of a range of numbers, one would have to find numbers that best represent the numbers in the collection that are closest to them.

For example, the two averages of the range from 1 to 5 are 2 and 4. 2 represents the numbers 1-3, while 4 represents the numbers 3-5. Below is a diagram to help understand why these numbers best represent the range.

[image]

A simple way to calculate the averages is to divide the range into equal parts and calculate the average of each part. For the previous example, the average of 1-3 is 2 and the average of 3-5 is 4.

### Challenge

Create a program that takes three inputs: a number *f*, another number *l* and a positive integer *n*, and outputs the *n* averages of the range of integers from *f* to *l*, inclusive. Assume that there are *n* or more numbers within this range.

### Rules

- Output can be a list/array or a string of numbers separated by spaces.
- The order of the output does not matter.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

### Test Cases

| *f* | *l* | *n* | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1.5, 2.5 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 25 | 2 | 9.25, 19.75 |
| 42 | -4 | 3 | 3.666..., 19, 34.333... |
| 0 | 27 | 4 | 3.375, 10.125, 16.875, 23.625 |
| 7 | 2.5 | 3 | 3.25, 4.75, 6.25 |

### Sandbox Questions

- Is the explanation clear enough?
- Is this challenge fit for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
- Is this challenge too hard or easy?
- What should be changed?

Comment: I don't understand the explanation at all (I know this isn't helpful feedback). Perhaps a test case, ideally with a step-by-step on how to get from the input to the output, will help us improve the explanation. Primarily, I don't understand how exactly you get multiple averages out of a list; isn't there just the one average being the sum divided by the count?

Comment: Answer to questions: 1. No, I can't understand what's gonna happen. 2. Yes, it is since it's most likely to be tasked with the shortest code possible. 3. It sounds easy, but no worries, challenges are not weighed by the difficulty, but it's fun. 4. Explanation, and you may want to add rule and winning criteria.

Comment: I'll try to fix the explanation and make it clearer. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Unlolify a lolified message!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235199/unlolify-a-lolified-message)

Comment: Welcome to the site! And thank you for using the sandbox.  I'm not sure what is meant by rule #2 could you clarify it further?

Comment: @WheatWizard Updated 1 and 2, trying to clarify it. Let me know if it's better :)

Comment: Ok, this is clearer.  Unicode however is not an encoding. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are encodings both of which are ASCII compliant.  Do you mean to say that the decoded string will only ever contain bytes less than 256?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say the decoded string will only have bytes less than 256! I meant to say that the whole Unicode isn't supported, but you are right -- ASCII is contained within it anyway. Edited trying to make that more clear, please let me know if you think if it's clear or what could improve!

Answer (score 0):

## Binary integer subtraction a - b with 0 < b < a using string processing logic  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [subtraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subtraction) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### My Work

I noticed that for this subtraction problem it is not necessary to use twos-complement and that the result can be stored in the same memory required to store `a`; all that is required is to employ symbolic/logic processing on bit/char-strings.

I wrote a Python program that uses `divmod`, but that was just a way of 'shifting-off'  the right most bit from the bitstring, so the code-golf answers should not use any arithmetical operations.

Here is my program, which can be taken to solve an implicit string processing specification:

```
minuend =    int(10**1111)
subtrahend = int(10**1110)

if True: #debugging
    minuend =    0b110101
    subtrahend = 0b000111
    M = minuend
    S = subtrahend

difference = ''
while 1: #State 0
    if minuend == 0:
        break
    minuend, m_right_bit = divmod(minuend, 2)
    subtrahend, s_right_bit = divmod(subtrahend, 2)        
    if     m_right_bit == 0 and s_right_bit == 0:
        difference = '0' + difference
    elif   m_right_bit == 1 and s_right_bit == 0:
        difference = '1' + difference
    elif   m_right_bit == 1 and s_right_bit == 1:
        difference = '0' + difference
    else:# m_right_bit == 0 and s_right_bit == 1:
        #State 1
        difference = '1' + difference
        while 1: #State 1
            if minuend == 0:
                break
            minuend, m_right_bit = divmod(minuend, 2)
            subtrahend, s_right_bit = divmod(subtrahend, 2)        
            if     m_right_bit == 0 and s_right_bit == 0:
                difference = '1' + difference
            elif   m_right_bit == 0 and s_right_bit == 1:
                difference = '0' + difference
            elif   m_right_bit == 1 and s_right_bit == 1:
                difference = '1' + difference
            else:# m_right_bit == 1 and s_right_bit == 0:
                difference = '0' + difference
                break # back to State 0     
            continue
    continue

if True: #debugging
    print('Answer (subtraction):', difference)    
    if int(difference, 2) != M -S:
        print('Program failed...')

raise SystemExit
```

### Challenge

Code to perform the same subtraction as my Python program; no output should be produced.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not how challenges work on our site. A code-golf challenge should be defined in terms of input and output, not by some internal behavior. Behavior (or algorithm) requirements are [non-observable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/78410).

Answer (score 0):

## Most Contrasting Background Color

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)

When putting colored text on a background, the text can sometimes be hard to read because the text color does not contrast with the background color well. Thus, this challenge will be to create a function or program that can find the most contrasting background color for a given text color.

### Challenge

Create a function or program that takes a text color (in RGB format) and outputs the farthest color from the text color, which would be either "black" or "white" as a string. This will be based on the [relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of the text color, which is an approximation of how light or dark a color is based on human perception. The relative luminance can be calculated with this formula:

\$Y=0.2126R+0.7152G+0.0722B\$

If the relative luminance is closer to 255 (white), then the program should output "black" and vice versa.

### Rules

- Output should be a string: "black" or "white".
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

### Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 255, 0, 0 | "white" |
| 0, 0, 0 | "white" |
| 255, 255, 255 | "black" |
| 0, 255, 255 | "black" |
| 133, 193, 230 | "black" |
| 100, 62, 139 | "white" |
| 128, 128, 128 | "black" |

### Sandbox Questions

- Is this a dupe?
- Is the challenge clear enough?
- What should be changed?

Comment: You should probably add an explanation for what relative luminance actually is.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert chessboards to algebraic notation

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

---

*Note: this is "simple" algebraic notation. It is only based off of my very limited knowledge. En passant, draw offers, disambiguation etc are not included and no bonuses will be given for handling those cases.*

[Algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) is a compact, universal chess notation which provides an easy method of communication between two chess players. There are many apps that can convert a game of chess into algebraic notation given a list of boards; in this challenge you will write one as well.

Before I go over the challenge details, here's a quick crash course of algebraic notation.

**Castling**: there are two types of castling: kingside castling, the "short" way, and queenside castling, the "long" way. The short way is denoted as `O-O` (or `0-0`) and the long way is `O-O-O` (or `0-0-0`). When castling is performed, the king and rook both move at the same time, making castling the only occasion when two pieces can move at the same time.

```
K..R -> .RK. (kingside)
R...K -> ..KR. (queenside)
```

**Other moves**: the rest of the time, only a single piece moves. The move's anatomy in algebraic notation looks like this:

- the first character is the piece type, **except** when a pawn is moving. In the case of the pawn the piece type is not included. Otherwise, a knight is `N`, king is `K`, rook is `R`, queen is `Q` and bishop is `B`.
- next, we add `x` if the move is a capture. If not add nothing.
- Then, as a chessboard "coordinate", the position that piece is moving to. For example `a4`, `b5` etc:

```
a8 b8 c8 d8 e8 f8 g8 h8
a7 b7 c7 d7 e7 f7 g7 h7
a6 b6 c6 d6 e6 f6 g6 h6
a5 b5 c5 d5 e5 f5 g5 h5
a4 b4 c4 d4 e4 f4 g4 h4
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3 g3 h3
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 g2 h2
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1
```

So a pawn moving to e4 would be `e4`, a bishop moving to h5 capturing a piece there would be `Bxh5`, a rook moving to g6 would be `Rg6`, etc. Note that pawn capturing at e4 would be `xe4`.

An additional character is placed at the end in certain circumstances: if the move makes the moving side "check" the opposing side then a `+` is added. For checkmates we add `#` instead. Note that this applies to castling as well (`O-O+`).

I will ignore en passant for this challenge.

### Now, for the challenge itself...

You will take in a sequence of boards representing an entire game, and output its corresponding algebraic notation.

I don't really care how you take the boards. You could take in a FEN string:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

or a 8-line, 8-column board:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

or a list of pieces:

```
['W', 'R', 'a8'], ...
```

or whatever else is reasonable. I will not accept taking in algebraic notation-like strings like `Ra8 Kb7`, for instance. You can take in a list of boards, double-newline separated, etc.

For each board you must output the algebraic notation of the move from the previous board to the current board by inferring the move from the difference between the boards, along with any necessary pluses and hashes in case the move is a check or checkmate. You must output the correct algebraic notation, but the end "list" can be of any format: a list, space-separated, newline-separated, etc. I don't really care as long as it is reasonable.

### Example

Two boards have been given.

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
.......N
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKB.R
```

Output:

```
Nh3
```

Another example:

```
....k...
........
........
K.......
....b...
....R...
........
.q......

....k...
........
........
K.......
....R...
........
........
.q......
```

Output:

```
Rxe4+
```

And finally, the Fool's mate with black castling once:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
........
........
........
.....P..
PPPPP.PP
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr
pppp.ppp
....p...
........
........
.....P..
PPPPP.PP
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkbnr
pppp.ppp
....p...
........
......P.
.....P..
PPPPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkb.r
pppp.ppp
....p..n
........
......P.
.....P..
PPPPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbqkb.r
pppp.ppp
....p..n
........
......P.
P....P..
.PPPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbqk..r
pppp.ppp
...bp..n
........
......P.
P....P..
.PPPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbqk..r
pppp.ppp
...bp..n
........
......P.
PP...P..
..PPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbq.rk.
pppp.ppp
...bp..n
........
......P.
PP...P..
..PPP..P
RNBQKBNR

rnbq.rk.
pppp.ppp
...bp..n
........
......P.
PP...P..
R.PPP..P
.NBQKBNR

rnb..rk.
pppp.ppp
...bp..n
........
......Pq
PP...P..
R.PPP..P
.NBQKBNR
```

Output:

```
f3 e6 g4 Nh6 a3 Bd6 b3 O-O Ra2 Qh4#
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the winner is the answer with the least bytes.

---

**Meta**: is this a duplicate? How could I improve the challenge further?

Comment: Not a dupe, but a lot more complex than it seems. Also, there are several ways to get to one position, and some involve backtracking - for example, how would an algorithm know how to get to a position with one black pawn advanced two squares?

Comment: @emanresuA This is "simple" algebraic notation, in the sense that any more complex types of moves are not considered. I'm not much of a chess expert myself.

Comment: What about, say, `Nf4 d5 Ng1`, with backtracking, and that's the only way to make it valid?

Comment: I know a little about chess, and no nothing about algebraic notation before. I'm confused that won't this cause ambiguous? Also, "check" and "checkmate" makes this challenge too complex, imo.

Comment: @tsh: I think it makes it more interesting, and more accurate as well as we are producing "more real" algebraic notation. I agree about ambiguities, but in the opening I decided that there would be no "disambiguation", partly because I'm not very familiar with the topic myself.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a number serious

I'm a big fan of silly challenges, but I'm afraid we're going to have to get serious. It's time to get rid of the lols.

Or rather, the `101`s, which look quite a bit like `lol`s.

**Task:**

Take an integer as input. You'll make this number serious by removing the `101`s from the number's binary representation. Now, particularly good jokes sometimes elicit `lolol`s or even `l(ol)+`s from numbers, so we must get rid of these too.

Comment: I suspect everything will be along the lines of `x.toString(2).replace(/(10)+1/g,'')`

Comment: Clarification: do we output the binary or the base10? Or whatever base we want?

Comment: @ykcul Must be number/decimal input and output, not a binary string

Comment: @emanresuA Well, `parseInt(x.toString(2).replace(/(10)+1/g,''),2)` :p

Answer (score 0):

C character constants.

I'm not sure if we had something like this before.

Given a value *n* between 1 and output the shortest possible c type character constant.

Examples:
1 -> '\1'
7 -> '\7'
8 -> '\b'
9 -> '\t'
65  ->  'A'

The character constants can only contain ASCII characters from 32 - 127.

Comment: But using `65` is shorter that using `'A'`

Comment: @tsh but 65 is not a character constant ;-)

Comment: You probably need to include an explanation of the valid character constants.

Comment: As far as I can see, replacing `'A'` by `65` would work in every cases of C codes (as C, not C++, doesn't support `auto` type). So, if you prefer shorter, you should really consider `65` instead of `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

## Fast Inverse Square Root *//evil floating point bit level hacking*

## Introduction

The fast inverse square root algorithm is a function developed in C for Quake III.  It was at the time the fastest way to compute the inverse square root of a function, which is needed for most vector operations.

The code as written in 1999, from the quake 3 source, is as follows:

```c
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the fuck? 
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

## Challenge

Given a floating-point number in any form you wish, calculate its inverse square root and return it as a float to at least 4 decimal places.

## Example

Input:

> 3

Output:

> 0.5773502691

## Judging

This is a challenge for creativity as well as code size.

For example, I would rate a 1:1 copy in c# about a 3/5, but a brainfuck copy 5/5 for the challenge and creativity.

Comment: I think this could be a cool challenge, it'll need some work though. I see you deleted the one you posted on main, if you want we can work through the problems it had here, then undelete it and edit it. I can tell you put a lot of work in to this, and it could be a good first draft of a great challenge!

Comment: The precision requirement "to at least 4 decimal places" isn't a good requirement since to verify it one would need to test the algorithm on every floating point number. Usually, a simpler way to handle floating point accuracy is to just give a large number of test cases and require that submissions meet all of them.

Comment: The "judging" section is extremely unclear at the moment. You mention that code size is important, but your examples make no mention of it. The examples you give are also for copying the algorithm, which I can't reasonably conclude to be creative. I'm not sure where you want to take this, but what you have now won't work.

Comment: might be one of the few that Rust does well in compared to other compiled languages, fn s(x:f64)->f64{1./x.sqrt()}

Answer (score 0):

## [Apply gravity to this matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235493/apply-gravity-to-this-matrix)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been done, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: FWIW, this is a fairly simple challenge (transpose, sort each row, transpose in most languages, some may even have a way of sorting each column directly)

Comment: Are the brackets required?

Comment: No, that was just to visualize Arrays. Input and output can be in any reasonable form.

Answer (score 0):

## [Encrypt this Message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235678/encrypt-this-message)

Answer (score 0):

## A *character*-less quine

Similar to “[What did we forget?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171789/95204)”

---

### Output

Your program must be a quine - that is, print its own source code with no input or unused input.

Although this is [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), you are allowed to read your own source code. Assume the file is named “q” and that no extension is needed. There is no bonus for not reading the source code.

If you remove all occurrences of a character that is in your program, it should print the character removed. It is allowed to then raise an error; however, there is no bonus for this either.

To the sandbox: **do I need this?** => Your program must have at least 3 different characters.

Lowest number of bytes wins (this *is* [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), after all)

### Sanbdox things

- Anything I should change?
- This used to be “Numberless” (see [edit history](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/23894/revisions)) - should I change it back?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening) [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Comment: I'm afraid it's [a duplicate of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171789/52210). PS: these type of challenges were characters are removed are tagged [tag:radiation-hardening].

Comment: Duplicate no longer…? The original source code must now be a quine.

Comment: Yep, seems to be no longer a duplicate. :) There are some radition-harderning + quine challenges, but most require to output the original program or current program after removing a single character.

Comment: Why are programs allowed to read their own source?  This rule seems a little disconnected to the rest of the challenge.

Comment: So it’s a little easier, I don’t want to be too harsh - it’s much harder if you can’t read your own source

Answer (score 0):

## [Drop down the numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235688/66833)

Comment: What happens when two non-zero entries ought to go to the same place?  For example" What if a column is `2, 1, 0`? What does that column become?

Comment: Also what if a number *can't* move down far enough? e.g. a `1` in the bottom row, or a `2` in the bottom two rows.

Comment: @WheatWizard Edited to clarify.

Comment: what do you mean by big number decide? Can you give out a simple example to explain it? thanks :D

Comment: @okie Explained

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's much clearer now, anyway, i think the second example's 4th row is wrong?

Comment: @okie Fixed. Any other problems with the test cases?

Comment: @AlanBagel I think it's good to go now! just remember to add rules and any extra stuff that you want to mention. For example: *standard rules applys* and such

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## Draw me a circle

Given a radius \$r\in\mathbb{N}\$ and \$r\geq 3\$, draw an ASCII circle for me, using \$x\$'s. Your circle does *not* have to look perfect, it just has to be identifiable as one. To make the circle look good, you have to use a \$2:1\$ ratio for width and height of the circles. This is due to characters being taller than wide.

One thing that is required though is an **appropriate** angle increment. I reccomend \$r\times3\$.

You do not have to account for float rounding errors!

Given the radius \$5\$, your output should look *similar* to this:

```
     x x x x x x     
    x           x    
 xx               xx 
 x                 x 
x                   x
 x                 x 
 xx               xx 
    x           x    
     x x x x x x
```

### IO

Input and output can be in any reasonable form.

### More test-cases

Note that these don't have to be an exact match!

```
3 ->   
        x x xx    
      xx       xx 
     x           x
      xx       xx 
         xx x x  

7 -> 
        xx x x x x xx        
      x               x      
    x                   x    
  xx                     xx  
 x                         x 
 x                         x 
x                           x
 x                         x 
 x                         x 
  xx                     xx  
    x                   x    
      x               x      
        xx x x x x xx
```

Comment: what does "appropriate angle increment?" mean? does it rule out drawing a circle without using angles?

Comment: how many percent of it should match? i could fill the entire board and say it match. I recommand giving a fixed shape and enlarge it with size increase.

Answer (score 0):

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

## Write an interpreter for "MathScript"

I had an idea for a new language, it's called MathScript! I got the idea from Mathematica.

Basically, this is how it works:

- Functions are called by using the following syntax:  `FunctionName{some, arguments, separated, by, commas}`
- The builtin functions are `Display`, `Add`, `Sub`, `Mul`, `IntDiv`, `FloorDiv`, `Pow`, `Factorial`, `FibN`, and `OddEvenQ`

The first few function names are pretty descriptive. `IntDiv` and `FloorDiv` calculate the integer division and floor division, respectively. `FibN` calculates the N'th Fibonacci number, and `OddEvenQ` returns 1 if a number is even and 0 if it is odd.

- Variables are created as so: `<Name> :: <Value>`
- The syntax for changing variables is the same as the syntax to change variables.
- The syntax for for loops are as following: `LoopN{<n>} :: [some, statements, separated, by, commas]`

## Test Cases

```
---
Display{Factorial{Add{2, 3}}} => 120
---

---
a :: 1
LoopN{3} :: [a :: Add{a, 1}, Display{a}] => 2 <newline> 3 <newline> 4 <newline>
---

---
num :: Add{Sub{1, 2}, Mul{Pow{2, 3}, Add{1, 2}}}
odd_or_even0 :: OddEvenQ{num}
num :: Factorial{num}
odd_or_even1 :: OddEvenQ{num}
Display{odd_or_even0} => 0
Display{odd_or_even1} => 1
---
```

## Scoring

This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the fastest answer wins. The testing will be on an i7 processer Windows 10 machine. The test case will be `LoopN{10} :: [LoopN{10} :: [Display{Add(2, Pow{3, 4})}]]`.

## Some clarification

Whitespace is ignored. Trailing commas in function arguments is allowed. You can assume that the input will always be correct. `Display` outputs something to stdout. Case is significant. (e. g Loopn != LoopN) If there are multiple statements, they can be separated by newlines or nothing at all. Blank lines can be anywhere.

## Language types

The types are the string (specified between double quotes or single quotes), the integer, and the float. Integers can be specified using normal numbers like 5 and 7383. The integer limit is [-2**32, 2**32] (32-bit). Floats can be specified using normal math notation, so these are all valid floats:

```
2.0
3.4
3.141592653
.8
2.
```

The `LoopN` function's first argument can be a integer literal, or a predefined variable.

## One Final Note

Compilers *are* allowed.

## Meta

- Any suggestions?
- Anything to clarify?

Comment: Is whitespace significant, or only used to separate tokens? Are trailing commas allowed? Will the input ever have a syntax error? What does display do? I assume it prints out something, but how does it print it out? Is case significant? If so, shouldn't your second test case should read `LoopN`? In your first test case you use `Print`, did you mean `Display`? The second test case seems to have multiple statements; how are statements separated? Are they always separated by newlines, or can it be any token separator? If they're always separated by newlines, can newlines appear anywhere else?

Comment: Every challenge has to have an objective scoring criterion; what is it for this challenge? Consider [tag:code-golf] or [tag:fastest-code].

Comment: I see that you've tagged this [tag:fastest-code]; this scoring criterion often involves a bit more work for the author, as all answers have to be scored on the same machine for fairness. If you use this scoring criterion, you should specify what machine you'll be running submissions on, as well as what test cases the input will be run on.

Comment: Some feedback re the language itself: there's no obvious conditional construct, though one can use `LoopN{<cond>} :: [ <body> ]` if `cond` is known to be either `0` or `1`, and `Pow{0, Pow{0, Pow{<cond>, 2}}}` to convert `<cond>` to `1` if non-zero, or `0` if `0`. Additionally, there's no obvious way to check for equality, other than using something like `Pow{0, Pow{Sub{A, B}, 2}}`, and no obvious way to check for greater than or less than.

Comment: More questions re the challenge: What are numbers? Are they all ints? All floats? What's the difference between `IntDiv` and `FloorDiv`? What are all of the valid ways to specify a number? What precision should be supported for numbers? Possible options include arbitrary precision (this would be helpful towards making the language turing-complete), implementation-defined (e.g. whatever your language supports), or something specific like IEEE-754 double precision floats.

Comment: How does `LoopN` work? Can you pass it a computed value, or does it have to be a number literal? If it's a computed value, is it recomputed every time, or stored after the first time? If it's recomputed, you could create while loops, which would be helpful for turing-completeness.

Comment: How many arguments do each of the functions take? What happens if a function is called with an incorrect number of arguments? Can that be assumed not to happen, or should some kind of error be outputted?

Comment: Does `FibN` support a non-positive index? If not, can it be assumed to not be called with that, or should an error be outputted? What happens if you divide by zero?

Comment: What happens if you call `Factorial` with a negative number? Does `Factorial` support an input of `0`? (it probably should)

Comment: If floats exist in the language, what does `OddEvenQ` do if you pass it a non-integer?

Comment: Are compilers allowed?

Comment: The second test case are looking weird, isn't the output should be `2 \n 3 \n 4 \n`?

Comment: I feel like you should add more MathScript programs to test with. An answer could optimize solely for the single test case you've given.

Answer (score 0):

## Irreducibile Polynomials

### in progress

### todo, add several test cases. and figure out how to deal with verifying answers.
figure out how references work, not just using plain  hyperlinks.

As you may know, Polynomials are mathematical expressions of the sum of a  variable raised to various powers and multiplied by various coefficients. For example consider the variable \$x\$

\begin{array}{11}
3x^2 & \mbox{ exponent is 2, leading coefficient is 3 } \\
3x^2 + 16x & \mbox { add a term with exponent = 1, coefficient = 16 } \\
3x^2 + 16x + 7 & \mbox { add another term, with exponent = 0, constant coefficient = 7 } \\
\end{array}

In general we can write a polynomial named \$P\$ as a function of \$x\$ as follows:
$$ P(x) = a_mx^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} ... + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x ^ 0 $$

Polynomials are somewhat similar to integers in that they can be factored into smaller polynomials that when multiplied together give the original polynomial. This process can be repeated until the integer or polynomial cannot be factored anymore. For integers this smallest factor is called a Prime, but for Polynomials it is called Irreducible. For integer polynomials over the integers, which is what this challenge is limited to, we have the following examples:

$$
\begin{array}{11}
\mbox{polynomial} & \mbox{irreducible factors} \\
x^2-1 & (x-1),(x+1) \\
x^5-x^4-2x^3-8x^2+6x-1 & (x^2 - 3x + 1),(x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x - 1) \\
6x^2 + 243x - 378 & (x+42),3,(2x-3) \\
\end{array}
$$

How do we know a polynomial is irreducible? We could do trial polynomial-division on all possible smaller polynomials, but it turns out that there are several algorithms that can quickly tell us if a polynomial is irreducible.

This challenge is to write a program that returns True if a given  Polynomial meets any of the four irreducibility criteria given below.

This is Code Golf - fewest number of bytes wins!

### Criteria 1: Gotthold Eisenstein

First your program should determine if the input polynomial meets the irreducibility criteria of [Gotthold Eisenstein](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/eisenstein.html). This criteria looks for the existence of a special number \$q\$ such that the following are true:

- \$q\$ is prime
- \$q\$ is not a factor of the Leading Coefficient
- \$q\$ ***is*** a factor of all the ***non***-Leading Coefficients
- \$q^2\$ is not a factor of the Constant Coefficient

For example:

$$P(x) = 3x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 10$$

has a \$q\$ of 5, where

- 5 is prime
- 5 is not a factor of the leading coefficient 3,
- 5 is a factor of the non-leading coefficients 15, -25, and 10
- 5 squared is not a factor of the constant coefficient 10

Therefore \$P\$ is irreducible, and your program should return True

### Criteria 2: Oskar Perron

In 1907 Oskar Perron's paper describes a [criteria that does not require factoring the coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_irreducibility_criterion). Recall that polynomial P can be written as

$$ P(x) = a_{m}x^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} ... + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x^0 $$

- Assume \$P\$ is monic, which means the leading coefficient \$a_{m}\$ is \$1\$.
- Assume \$a_0\$ is not \$0\$
- If the absolute value of \$a_{m-1}\$ is greater than the sum of all the other coefficient's absolute value, then \$P\$ is irreducible
- In more mathy language:

$$ |a_{m-1}| > \sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\neq{m-1}}}^{m} |a_i| \implies P \mbox{ is irreducible} $$

Example:

- \$P(x)=x^{38797389} - 55x^2 + 2x - 9\$
- \$a_m=1\$ and \$a_0 \ne 0\$
- \$|a_{m-1}| = 55\$
- Sum of other coefficients absolute value is \$1+2+9 = 12\$
- \$55 > 12\$

Therefore \$P\$ is irreducible, and your program should return True

### Criteria 3: Michael Filaseta 1988

Next we visit [Michael Filaseta's 1988 paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/irreducibility-criteria-for-polynomials-with-nonnegative-coefficients/A507ABBDF3D0A59A08A2C754BA7A7565) in which he describes the following wonderful criteria: If \$P(x)\$ is an integer polynomial of degree \$<= 31\$ which has non-negative coefficients, and \$P(10)\$ is prime, then \$P\$ is irreducible.

For example:

- \$ P(x) = x^8+2x^4+23 \$
- \$P\$ is of degree 8, which is less than or equal to 31
- \$ P(10) = 100020023 \$
- \$100020023\$ is prime

Therefore \$P\$ is irreducible, and your program should return True

#### Criteria 4: Filaseta and Gross

In 2014 Filaseta and Samuel Gross published the following [remarkable criteria, which doesn't depend on the degree of the polynomial](https://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/papers/FilGrossPap2013Submitted.pdf):

- Consider \$P(x)\$ an integer polynomial with coefficients between \$0\$ and \$49598666989151226098104244512918\$.
- If \$P(10)\$ is prime then \$P\$ is irreducible

For example

- \$ P(x) = 54x^{38} + 78783x^{33} + 035033459404x^{21} + 1190354877x^{11} + 56007093177 \$
- all coefficients are between \$0\$ and \$49598666989151226098104244512918\$
- \$ P(10)= 5478783035033459404119035487756007093177 \$
- \$5478783035033459404119035487756007093177\$ is prime

Therefore \$P\$ is irreducible, and your program should return True

#### Input format

The input format can be whatever is easiest for your language, and if your language has built-in polynomials, that is allowed. The test-case  polynomials can be converted to your chosen format before processing into your program. You can take input as an argument to a function, as standard input, or whatever is easiest for your language.

If your language has no built-in polynomial format, one suggestion is to look at the [PolyNumber](https://youtu.be/KbNYsNWRtzs?t=499) format - that is, an array listing the coefficients, and the position within the array indicating the exponent. Lowest powers come first. For example

$$x^2+1 \mbox { is } [1,1] $$
$$2x^3+5x^2+7x+4 \mbox { is } [4,7,5,2] $$
$$x^4 + 5 \mbox{ is } [ 5,0,0,0,4 ] $$

#### Extra notes

First, please note these criteria are sufficient but not necessary. This means that if a polynomial meets the criteria, then it is irreducible. However, just because it doesn't meet the criteria, that doesn't mean it's not irreducible. For the challenge, your program just needs to return True if an irreducibility criteria is satisfied. Returning a non-True value will simply indicate the criteria were not satisfied, it won't necessarily mean that the input polynomial is or isn't irreducible.

Second, a quick glossary of terminology, for polynomial \$P\$ we have the function

$$P(x) = a_mx^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} ... + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x ^ 0 $$

- Leading Coefficient - the coefficient of the highest power term: \$a_m\$
- Constant Coefficient - the coefficient of the 0th power term: \$a_0\$
- Degree - The value of the highest exponent: \$m\$
- Integer Polynomial - a polynomial where all coefficients are integers
- Monic Polynomial - a polynomial with Leading Coefficient of 1

For example let us create an integer polynomial with degree 9, a leading coefficient of 42, and a constant coefficient of -7, as follows:

$$ 42x^9-7  $$

### Refs

Filaseta, M. (1988). Irreducibility Criteria for Polynomials with non-negative Coefficients. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 40(2), 339-351. doi:10.4153/CJM-1988-013-6

https://bigprimes.org/

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X13002539

Comment: It's clear that a lot of work has gone into this, but I question whether asking for solutions to test against multiple rigid criteria (one of which includes a 32 byte constant) isn't pulling in the opposite direction to code golf. It's unclear to me how much scope there is for creativity here, since each criterion includes a prescribed set of conditions that are mostly independent of each other. Have you considered just asking whether a given polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: well its a good point but... but i was hoping that these four techniques are not as independent as they appear to be at first glance. Also asking "is this irreducible" only has one answer, to fully factor the polynomial, which systems like Mathematica automatically will win.

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Halve Code Regen

TODO: This is a horrible title.

Your challenge is to write a program, and when I half the program, the output must stay the same. Then, I will halve it and add the last two characters, and the output should be the same with the program's last two characters at the end.

Sometimes the code can't be halved evenly, and when that happens, I will do something similar to floor division:

```
blahy => bl
horse => ho
meddle => med (regular halving)
oof => o
```

##### Example for "the output should be the same with the program's last two characters at the end"

Let's say we have this code:

```
q|w_a2e(o+2ei2ere
```

and the output is

```
q|w_a2e(o+2ei2ere
```

when I change it to

```
q|w_a2e(o+2ei2erere
```

by adding the last two characters (`re`), the output should look like

```
q|w_a2e(o+2ei2erere
```

(Note the extra `re` at the)

## Rules

- No padding with comments
- The program must have at least 2 characters.
- Standard loopholes apply
- The output cannot be empty.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the least bytes wins.

##### How I came up with the random code in the example two sections ago

`q` means quine. `|` is a separator. `w_a2e` means when the last two characters are added to the end. `(o+2e` means add the last two characters to the end. `i2ere` means ignore a repeated `2e` at the end.

## Meta

- Is this even possible?
- If so, any other suggestions?

Comment: I think this would be more interesting if multiple halves of the program had to work.  Otherwise it's just output something (or nothing since it doesn't look like you've ruled that out.) and then pad the program out with comments.

Comment: @WheatWizard Fixed. Any idea for a better title?

Comment: That's not quite what I meant.  I mean that splitting the same program in half multiple ways ought to preserve the output.

Comment: Also you should definitely restrict the output further.  At the very least it should have to be non-empty. You should also require the programs to be at least 1 or 2 bytes long.

Comment: @WheatWizard Fixed.

Comment: I still can't decide on a better title, though.

Comment: I don't understand what the "the output should be the same with the program's last two characters at the end" part means. Can you show a full example of what you do to the program?

Answer (score 0):



Answer (score 0):

## Hearts KotH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is to write a Java bot to play a simplified version of hearts.

Hearts is a four-player trick-based card game. To start a round of hearts, each player is dealt 13 cards. The player who has the two of clubs starts by playing the two of clubs. Going around the circle each player plays another card, in the same suit as as the first card if possible. Once every player has played one card, the trick is complete, and goes to the player who placed the highest valued card in the original suit (aces are high). The player who takes the trick is responsible for all of the points contained in the trick, as well as leading the next trick. This continues until all players are out of cards, at which point the hand is complete.

During a hand, each heart taken is worth 1 point and the queen of spades 13 points. If during the course of a hand one player receives all 26 points, they shoot the moon and receive zero while everyone else receives 26 points. The game ends once a player clears 100 points, at which point the player with the lowest score wins.

### The Challenge ​

Write a Java 11 bot extending a (todo) abstract class. A new bot will be instantiated for each hand. Every combination of 4 bots will play one game with each other. After all of the games are complete, the bots will be scored on the total number of wins (higher is better), with the tiebreaker being the average score per game (lower is better).

Tampering with the controller, tampering or instantiating other bots, damaging my computer, taking an excessively long time to complete a turn, failing to compile, violating standard loopholes, or throwing a runtime `Error` is strictly prohibited and will result in disqualification. Throwing an exception will result in a 1 point penalty and the controller playing for you in an unspecified manner. Nondeterministic bots and storing data between both Hands and games are permitted.

### Meta:

Is this clear enough?

I haven't written the controller yet, is there any data in particular that you would like to see the bots receive (among other things, a way to determine the legality of the move, as well as cards played are already passed in)?

Comment: How are the cards distributed? If it's random, I'm worried there won't be much strategy possible and it'll mostly just be a random outcome.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms the plan right now is random, but it doesn't have to be. My theory was that since there are typically 5-10 hands per game in real life, the law of large numbers would win out. In real life, while the game is slightly more complicated all strategies boil down to card counting and probability-based heuristics anyway, and you can get quite good at it.

Comment: It seems like card counting and probability based heuristics would both make for a pretty boring KotH, since while they'd be challenging to keep track of as a human, a bot could be optimized without too much work being necessary.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms the way things are set up currently, the relatively boring task of counting cards is mostly handled by the controller. Also, most KotH challenges have been probability based heuristics, like the various rock paper scissors challenges and the various prisoner's dilemma based challenges. Still, if the consensus seems to be that this won't do very well I will head back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

## Optimize my Cruise Control

My cars cruise-control functionality has 4 different methods of adjustment, all using a single stalk.  They are as follows:

- Hard press up (press until you feel the click): +5 mph
- Soft press up (press lightly, but not to the click): +1 mph
- Soft press down (press lightly, but not to the click): -1 mph
- Hard press down (press until you feel the click): -5 mph

If your current speed is not a multiple of 5, a hard press will take you up/down to the nearest 5 multiple.

The challenge is to write a function that takes your current speed and target speed as parameters, and outputs the shortest sequence of stalk inputs to get from current -> target speed.

Rules:

- Take 2 integers as input
- Return a list/iterable/whatever of the minimum actions needed to get to target speed

Examples:
(`U` is hard up, `u` is soft up, `d` is soft down, `D` is hard down)

```
[5, 6] -> [u]
[20, 37] -> [U,U,U,u,u]
[42, 45] -> [U]
[16,23] -> [U,u,u,u] or [U,U,d,d]
```

### currently known issues

- needs more examples
- similar to the Optimal Change problem.

### Other possible improvements

- Maybe make it a more generalized function that takes 4 inputs [v_current, v_target, delta_small, delta_large].  This would have the effect of complicating the logic and making the problem a bit less trivial.

Answer (score 0):

## [Balanced Bracket Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236143/)

Answer (score 0):

## Pattern in Prime

Given a positive integer less than 100 with no preceding zeros we have to find all 12 digit primes that contains the maximum number of time the given pattern.

Note: Pattern's occurance can overlap. For example 11 occur 6 times in 1111111

Example:

pattern = 1 , count = 13
the maximum occurance is in 111111110111, eleven, and those 12 digit primes are
{101111111111,111011111111,111111011111,111111110111,111111111101,111111111511,111111111611,111111211111,111113111111,111211111111,111511111111,116111111111,311111111111}

pattern = 22  , count = 1
{522222222229}

pattern = 69, count = 162

pattern = 37, count = 151

Output format: first line should be count of such primes, and then print the primes in sorted order

If possible while answering please write a short explanation of what you did. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes per language wins.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime) [pattern-matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching)

Answer (score 0):

## Best Rotation

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)
If we rotate a raster image by some angle that is not a multiple of \$90°\$, we will have to use some kind of interpolation. Depending on what kind of interpolation method we use, we get a better or a worse quality. This is especially apparent if we repeat the rotation multiple times. In the following image we se the original on the top left, and then the result of different interpolation methods when used to rotate the original \$360\$ times by \$1°\$.

[image: salvator mundi]
\$\renewcommand\phi\varphi\$

## Challenge

Given some angle \$\phi\$ Your task is to find a method to find a (deterministic) function \$f_\phi\$ that takes some image \$I\$ and rotates it by \$\phi\$.

## Scoring (not solved yet)

**META** this is the issue. Ideally we'd like to have some *objective* criterion. But so far I have not managed to find one that cannot be gamed:

1. If we just let the participants rotate an image by some angle \$\phi\$ how can we then compare it to the "exact" solution? Maybe their method is better than the best standard method, even if they have to apply it repeatedly. So it seems we can only truly check against a total rotation that is a multiple of \$90°\$.
2. Let's say we say we use an angle of \$\phi = 2\pi/n\$ and let them apply their "rotation" \$n\$ times to measure e.g. the \$l^2\$-error \$E = \Vert I - f_\phi(\ldots f_\phi(I)\ldots)\Vert_2\$ . This means they could just use \$f_\phi = id\$.
3. If we instead use a total rotation of e.g. \$\pi/2\$ (that is \$\phi = \frac{\pi}{2n}\$, with \$n\$ rotations). Then the participants could just use some permutation of pixels that just happens to rotate the image after \$n\$ rotations exactly (or maybe exactly except for some pixels).

So does anyone have another suggestion of how to objectively measure it without introducing any hand-wavey rules?

Comment: My gut feeling is that if this problem were phrasable in an objective manner it would basically already be solved.

Comment: @WheatWitch Maybe it is solved but I don't think the objective "rules" matter - I'm just trying to make rules that don't have loopholes. For instance for the approach of measuring the error of repeted rotations totalling 90° I'd like that the intermediate images also look very much like the original. Any "sane" algo would obey that, but I just struggle to find a way to enforce this without any hand-waveyness.

Comment: As an alternative I'm considering actually dropping the idea of seeking "sane" algorithms and encouraging pathologic algorithms that manage to do great 90° rotations while having visually nonsense intermediate images. But I think that this is trivial, as I outlined in (3.).

Comment: A third idea would be some kind of [tag:king-of-the-hill] where each submission will be paired with every other submission to rotate the image a total of 90° and then find some kind of average score.

Answer (score 0):

**Integer points on Hyperspheres**

Given two non-negative integers \$r\$ and \$d\$, write a program that will output the number of integer points that lie on all hyperspheres of dimension \$d\$ or lower with radius \$r\$ or lower.

For example, given \$r = 5, d = 2\$, the program would do something like this:

The hypersphere of dimension 2 is a circle. The radius is 5. There are 12 integer points on this circle, as follows:
$$(5,0),(4,3),(3,4),(0,5),(-3,4),(-4,3),(-5,0),(-4,-3),(-3,-4),(0,-5),(3,-4),(4,-3)$$

If the radius is 4, there are 4 integer points:
$$(4,0),(0,4),(-4,0),(0,-4)$$

If the radius is 3, again it's 4 integer points. If the radius is 2, again 4. Radius 1 - again, 4. Radius 0 has only 1 integer point. If we add all these up it's 12 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 , or **29** points total for the 2 dimensional hyperspheres with radius \$<=5\$.

Now if we take the dimension 1 hypersphere, it is interpreted as 2 points in  a one dimensional space, distance r from the origin. For example the 1 dimensional hypersphere with radius 5 has only two points, $$(5),(-5)$$ and their coordinates are only single dimensional. So, the dimension 1 hypersphere with radius 5 has two integer points. The dimension 1 hypersphere with radius 4 also has 2 integer points, and so on. The total integer points on all 1 dimensional hypspheres with radius 0 to 5 is 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1, or **11**.

The dimension 0 hypersphere is defined for this challenge to have 0 points.

So the final output of a program with input \$r = 5, d = 2\$ will be 29 + 11 + 0, or **40**.

- You may assume that r and d will be low enough so that the integer type of your language will be large enough so that it can represent the answer. In other words if your language has only 16 bit integers, then you can write a program that assumes r and d will be low enough so that the final answer is between 0 and 65535.
- This is Code Golf, lowest # of bytes wins

Comment: This is essentially Pythagorean triples but generalised to `d`-tuples, right? (and allowing 0)

Comment: i think so, yes, that sounds correct...

Answer (score 0):

## Same String Regardless of Repetition

### Challenge

Write a full program that prints a string that has a length of at least 1. When the source code is repeated any amount of times, that string should still be outputted. For example, if my source code is `ABC` and it prints `Hello, World!`, then `ABCABC` will still print `Hello, World!` and `ABCABCABC` will also print `Hello, World!` and etc.

### Rules

- It has to be a full program that takes no input (or have an unused input if this is impossible) and prints the string to STDOUT.
- The program and the string have to be at least 1 byte long.
- The strings that are outputted with each repetition have to be exactly the same. Trailing or leading spaces make the strings different.
- There must be only one output.
- There is no code between repetitions.
- Comments in your code are not allowed.
- This is code-golf, so programs are scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

Comment: I’m not too sure if “comments are not allowed” is an easy rule to enforce… everything else seems fine, +1 from me

Comment: Maybe require the program to print a number alongside the `Hello, World!` to enforce that the code has to account for the repetitions? so `ABC` => `1. Hello, World!`, `ABCABC` => `2. Hello, World!` etc., and just make sure to specify that code can't read itself? This way, if you just comment out the rest of the code, it will fail.

Comment: To avoid comment abuse and answers along the lines of `print('Hello, World!');exit;` you could require the program to be [irreducible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824/92901). However I suspect this challenge will still be really easy in most golfing languages. [Here](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Xz0RBP//BwA "Japt – Try It Online") is an example (2 byte program repeated 3 times), and I don't even know Japt.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve linear equations over the integers

All variables in this question are integer valued.

## Input

4 integers w, x, y, z. They can be positive or negative and will be less than 1048576 in absolute value.

## Output

The general solution to the equation.

\$ aw+bx+cy+dz = 0 \$.

The variables \$a, b, c, d\$ must all be integer values.

## Output format

Your output should consist of three tuples each with four parts, one for each of the values a, b, c, d. Let me explain by example:

```
Input: -118, 989, 918, -512

Answer: b = 2 n_0 
        c = 9 n_0 + 256 n_1 + 81 a
        d = 20 n_0 + 459 n_1 + 145 a
```

Explanation:  `n_0` and `n_1` are integers that you can set to anything you like. The solution says: `a` can also be set to any integer value, `b` must be twice whatever you set `n_0` to.
This means that `a` can be set to any integer, `c` can now be calculated in terms of three variables we have already set and so can `d`.

The format of your output should be 3 tuples (#,#,#,#), (#,#,#,#), (#,#,#,#). We can assume three free integer variables n0, n1 and n2 and so  (a,b,c,d) = (#,#,#,#)n0 + (#,#,#,#)n1 + (#,#,#,#)n2.  In the example above the output would therefore be:

```
Output: (0, 2, 9, 20), (0, 0, 256, 459), (1, 0, 81, 145)
```

## Examples

Example one:

```
 Input: -6, 3, 7, 8

 Answer:  c = 2a + 3b + 8n
          d = -a - 3b - 7n 
          n is any integer

Output: (1, 0, 2, -1), (0, 1, 3, -3), (0, 0, 8, -7)
```

Example two:

```
Input: -116, 60, 897, 578

Answer: c = 578 n + 158 a + 576 b
        d = -897 n - 245 a - 894 b 
        n is any integer

Output: (1, 0, 158, -245), (0, 1, 576, -894), (0, 0, 578, -897)
```

Example three:

```
Input: 159, -736, -845, -96

Output: (1, 0, 27, -236), (0, 1, 64, -571), (0, 0, 96, -845)
```

## Discussion

To understand this challenge further it is worth looking at this possible general solution which does **not** work `[(z, 0, 0, -w), (0, z, 0, -x), (0, 0, z, -y)]`.  The problem with this is that there are solutions to the problem instances above which are not the sum of any integer multiples of those tuples. For example: take input -6, 3, 7, 8 from Example 1.  The proposed solution would give the tuples:

```
(8, 0, 0, 6), (0, 8, 0, -3), (0, 0, 8, -7)
```

Why doesn't this work?

There is a solution for this instance with a = 1, b = 1, c = 13, d = -11 because `-6+3+7*13-11*8 = 0`. However there are no integers n_0, n_1, n_2 to make `n_0 * (8, 0, 0, 6) + n_1 * (0, 8, 0, -3) + n_2 * (0, 0, 8, -7) = (1, 1, 13, -11)` .

Comment: I expect the most common form of outputs would be `(a,b,c,d) = (#,#,#,#)x + (#,#,#,#)y + (#,#,#,#)z`, where `#`s are some integer constants and `x,y,z` are free variables. In this case, may I simply output the three vectors of length 4?

Comment: @Bubbler. The inputs are labelled w,x,y,z.  I assume your x,y,z are not those?

Comment: I mean, `(a,b,c,d) = (#,#,#,#)n0 + (#,#,#,#)n1 + (#,#,#,#)n2` if it reads better. Or in four separate equations: `a = #n0 + #n1 + #n2; b = #n0 + #n1 + #n2; ...`.

Comment: @Bubbler what worries me slightly about that formulation is that it might force the coefficients to be really large.  You seem to get much smaller coefficients if you express the variables in terms of previous ones and some free variables.

Comment: No, the coefficient size is irrelevant. Your example output in my format is `a = 0*n_0 + 0*n_1 + 1*n_2; b = 2*n_0 + 0*n_1 + 0*n_2; c = 9*n_0 + 256*n_1 + 81*n_2; d = 20*n_0 + 459*n_1 + 145*n_2`, or `(a,b,c,d) = (0,2,9,20)n_0 + (0,0,256,459)n_1 + (1,0,81,145)n_2` in short. I'm only asking about the output format here. Is outputting `[[0,2,9,20], [0,0,256,459], [1,0,81,145]]` OK?

Comment: Let me think if you would ever have to express d in terms of c which in turn is expressed in terms of b.

Comment: Such situation can always be simplified to my form using substitution followed by expansion.

Comment: Yes. That’s where my concern about coefficient size comes in I believe.

Comment: Why are you concerning about the coefficient size in the first place? Isn't it plain code golf and we're allowed to output *any* solution that solves the problem I assume?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn’t worry about it.  You can solve the problem so that you get ugly answers with huge coefficients (which is what sympy does).  I thought it would be good to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. But still you didn't answer my original question about the output format.

Comment: If you have to scale your byte count by a factor which is how much larger (in absolute value) your largest coefficient is than the examples is that then code-challenge?

Comment: I really like your output format. I am just trying to work if it causes problems which I want to avoid. An alternative is to have 3 coefficients for a, 4 for b, 5 for c and 6 for d. That would enable you to express each one in terms of both the free variables and the other variables.

Comment: No, mixing code length with some other metric doesn't work (believe me, [I tried it once and failed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157238/78410)). Just go pure code-challenge (must run in reasonable amount of time, smallest coefficient wins) or pure code-golf (no time limit, output anything valid). For the former, you also need to prepare a good amount of hidden test cases ([tag:test-battery]), otherwise you can't avoid hardcoded solutions.

Comment: The point is that "fully general format" as in your examples is way too tedious to actually output in non-Mathematica languages, so I'm suggesting a structured output which tries to simplify that. And all possible outputs can be expressed in the format I'm suggesting. If you decided for code-golf, you should **absolutely** stop worrying about the coefficient size. Please.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really useful advice.

Comment: This is solvable by just doing `[(z, 0, 0, -w), (0, z, 0, -x), (0, 0, z, -y)]` - see this message for explanation: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59453995

Answer (score 0):

In 1960 [Andrey Kolmogorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov) conjectured that any algorithm to multiply two integers would require \$\Omega(n^2)\$<sup>*</sup> steps.

Within a week of presenting this conjecture it was proven false by graduate student Anatoly Karatsuba.  [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is an algorithm to multiply two numbers which takes in the worst case \$O(n^{\log_2 3})\$ time.

Your task will be to implement this algorithm.  You will receive as input two binary strings.  These can be lists of ints, arrays of bools etc.

You should then output the binary representation of their product in the same format.

It's hard to say in precise terms what it means to implement a particular algorithm.  So here we will require only that your algorithm have asymptotic time complexity of \$O(n^{\log_2 3})\$ and \$\Omega(n^{\log_2 3})\$ where \$n\$ is the total number of bits in the input.  Which is to say that it is neither better nor worse than Karatsuba's algorithm up to a constant factor.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with lower bytes being the goal.

---

<sup>* In this challenge we will use \$f\in \Omega(g)\$ to mean that \$\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\$ does not converge to \$0\$.  Also stated as \$f \in \Omega(g) \iff \exists k.\forall x.\exists x'.f(x')\geq k\cdot g(x')\$.  This is the Hardy-Littlewood definition.</sup>

Comment: [Python is known to use the exact algorithm under the hood](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b514339e41ef/Objects/longobject.c#l2694), and it may be true for some other langs as well. Is it OK to use such built-in? Also, is it OK to use even faster multiplication and just slow it down with dummy recursion?

Comment: As bubbler mentioned, I would suggest remove the lower bound from the question, as the answer may implement a better algorithm (I don't know if it exist or not) and then slow it down by appending some dummy operations.

Comment: Also, you should explain what does \$n\$ means in the formula (length of input). As it is not very clear to readers.

Comment: @tsh is "where n is the total number of bits in the input." unclear? I'm not sure how I can explain it more directly than that.

Comment: @Bubbler RE builtins:  I don't ban builtins, I don't think it makes challenges better and only leads to confusion.  It's up to the user whether they want to have fun.  RE faster algos: The point of this challenge to implement this algorithm, not faster ones.  The lower bound is there to encourage the algo.  If you use a faster algorithm you are going to have to pay the cost to pad it out to the correct run time.

Comment: I guess it could be better to further specify "the total number of bits of *the two input numbers*". Also probably move it closer to the first use of n.

Comment: @Bubbler Technically the \$n\$ in the initial statement is a little more complex.  It's just a explainer so I don't think it's worth getting into all the details when in basically works like the default meaning of \$n\$.

Answer (score 0):

[posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237016/make-a-scrabble-world-finder)

Comment: Will input word contains duplicate characters? What is expected output for `top, [to, two, too]`, `equipment, [queue, queen, quine]`?

Comment: Updated examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237007/concatenation-coincidence)

Answer (score 0):

## [Infinite ordinals from a well-ordering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237291/infinite-ordinals-from-a-well-ordering)

Comment: Are the score categories essentially arbitrary? If so, it's not clear to me whether this is a good idea: it seems like these constraints provide the only motivation for choosing a well-ordering different from the 'default' (1, 2, 3, ...). Poor constraint choices could derail the challenge (i.e. make it too trivial or too hard). On the subject of scoring, looking at the bytes category for example, do you mean that if the default ordering is chosen, the code must be exactly 1 byte?

Comment: Also, there's a typo under the second example: `2 < 101` is *true*.

Comment: @Dingus I tried to clarify the scoring part. So if you choose \$\omega\cdot 2\$ you just try to golf an implementation of it. In this case someone has (hypothetically) managed to do it in one byte. As for the difficulty of the ordinals, the first two are one-liners in most languages, \$\omega^\omega\$ can be implemented with a while loop and \$\epsilon_0\$ with a tree.

The score categories are not totally arbitrary. \$epsilon_0\$ is an important ordinal, and the smaller ones follow a natural pattern. Another option is to have just one ordinal, making this a normal golf and not a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## [Convert codepoint to UTF-1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237526/100411)

Answer (score 0):

## Implement every dirname (1p)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Implement the [dirname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) utility **from scratch**. It can be either a program or a fucntion. Assume input string satisfies these constraints:

- it contains [portable filename character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) only, and
- its length is up to 256 bytes, including trailing a NULL character ([as in `_POSIX_PATH_MAX` from limits.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)).

The dirname utility, however, has two kinds of implementations. This is because [some POSIX systems treat //foo/bar differently from /foo/bar.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497/451199) So in this challenge, you must output every possible outputs, in any order. They can be duplicated.

Here is the algorithm to implement the utility, provided *string* to be input:

> 1. If *string* is **//**, skip steps 2 to 5.
> 2. If *string* consists entirely of <slash> characters, *string* shall be set to a single <slash> character. In this case, skip steps 3 to 8.
> 3. If there are any trailing <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 4. If there are no <slash> characters remaining in *string*, *string* shall be set to a single <period> character. In this case, skip steps 5 to 8.
> 5. If there are any trailing non- <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 6. If the remaining *string* is **//**, it is implementation-defined whether steps 7 and 8 are skipped or processed.
> 7. If there are any trailing <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 8. If the remaining *string* is empty, *string* shall be set to a single <slash> character.

The final *string* is the output.

Standard I/O rules apply. Standard Loopholes apply. No builtins or libraries that does exactly same functionality. Shortest code wins.

## Examples

Some examples are taken from [POSIX explaination of basename()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html).

`*` means an empty string. 1st column is input and 2nd and 3rd are possible outputs.

```
usr               .
usr/              .
*                 .
..                .
../               .
/                 /
//                /          //
///               /
/usr/             /
//usr/            /          //
///usr/           /
/usr/lib          /usr
//usr//lib//      //usr
/home//dwc//test  /home//dwc
```

## Meta

- ?

Answer (score 0):

## [Write a Stack Exchange compliant brainfuck explainer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237408/write-a-stack-exchange-compliant-brainfuck-explainer)

Comment: @Adám But i prefer using 4 spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by stating your preferences. Either it is allowed, or not.

Comment: `~` is ascii 126

Comment: I would suggest avoid characters `[]` in description so they are ensured to be comment.

Comment: @tsh Oh, that's interesting, then the code remains runnable, even when fully explained.

Comment: I still strongly recommend giving the explanation strings as an argument, or even giving both explanation strings and symbols as arguments; that'd make the solution into a general code explainer.

Answer (score 0):

## Golf a Friedman's tree sequence for 3 colors

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)
[busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

Friedman proved that given a sequence of 3-labelled rooted trees with following conditions, TREE sequence, must be finite and defined maximum length of such sequence as `TREE(3)`.

- \$i\$th tree, \$T_i\$, should have no more than \$i\$ vertices. (index is 1-based)
- No tree \$T_i\$ can be homeomorphically embeddable into any of the following tree \$T_j\$ if \$i < j\$.

  - A tree \$A\$ is said to be homeomorphically embeddable to tree \$B\$ if and only if there exists a function \$f\$ from vertices of \$A\$ to vertices of \$B\$ which satisfies following conditions:

    1. \$f\$ preserves label. That is, \$v\$ and \$f(v)\$ has same label.
    2. If \$u\$ is ancestor of \$v\$, then \$f(u)\$ is ancestor of \$f(v)\$.
    3. If \$u_1\$ and \$u_2\$ are children of \$v\$, then the path from \$f(u_1)\$ to \$f(u_2)\$ contains \$f(v)\$.
  - There is a guide with examples in [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/3P6DWAwwViU).

It is well known that `TREE(3)` is far larger than \$2^{64}\$.

## Challenge

Find a TREE sequence with length of \$2^{64}\$ or longer.
Your task is to implement a program or a function or a subroutine that takes one 64-bit integer \$i\$ and outputs a tree \$T_i\$ of your TREE sequence.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- Standard I/O rules apply.
- Shortest code wins.
- Output can be any format as long as it describes a 3-labelled tree.
- Describe how your outputs form valid TREE sequence.

## Example of valid sequence, length 16

```
1 - {}              # 1 vertex tree with label {}. Note that any tree after this cannot contain node with label {}.
2 - [[]]            # 2 vertex tree with label both []. Any tree after this cannot contain two ancestor-child node with both label [].
3 - [(())]
4 - ([][])          # Root with label (), 2 children with label [].
5 - ([]((())))
6 - ([](()))
7 - [()]
8 - []
9 - ((((((((()))))))))
10 - (((((((())))))))
11 - ((((((()))))))
12 - (((((())))))
13 - ((((()))))
14 - (((())))
15 - ((()))
16 - (())
```

## Meta

This is my first challenge. Suggestions?

I'm sure that normal computers will have serious difficulty to execute code for this problem, but also I don't want answers to just brute force TREE sequence and print ith term. How can I balance the question?

Comment: You definitely need some examples of the rules. Also, "homeomorphically embeddable" is not a term the average codegolfer is familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

## Escape the maze

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)

## Introduction

Here is a random maze:

```
#####
#M.#E
#.##.
#.##.
#....
#####
```

Here `M` is the starting point and `E` is the endpoint. `#` is a maze wall and `.` is a path.

Now we can get out of this maze by following the sequence `sssdddwww`. (`s` is dow, `d` is right, `w` is up, `a` is left.)

## Your challenge

Given a maze, output the *shortest* possible route to the endpoint. (`E`) You may assume the maze is solvable.

## Test cases

```
#####
#M.#E
#.##.
#.##.
#....
#####
```

outputs

```
#####
#..#E
#M##.
#.##.
#....
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#M##.
#....
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#.##.
#M...
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#.##.
#.M..
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#.##.
#..M.
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#.##.
#...M
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##.
#.##M
#....
#####

#####
#..#E
#.##M
#.##.
#....
#####

#####
#..#M
#.##.
#.##.
#....
#####
```

(Notice the newlines between the steps.)

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

---

#### Todo

- Add more test cases
- Maybe some custom scoring or [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

Comment: Welcome to Meta code golf. add tag [tag:maze] :p

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Done.

Comment: Dupe of [Find the shortest path from point A to point B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28740/92901). That challenge has itself been closed as a dupe of [Textual maze solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2225/92901), a decision I don't necessarily agree with, but better to reopen the existing challenge than create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

## Solve the halting problem for Minyrinth [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) [halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem)

### Introduction

Minyrinth is the stripped-down version of [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth). It has the same routing semantics as Labyrinth but only four non-wall commands, and only one register (that can hold unbounded signed integers) instead of two stacks. The register is initialized to zero.

#### Commands

- `"` is a no-op path.
- `@` halts the program.
- `)` increments the register.
- `(` decrements the register.

You may assume that the input only contains the four command characters plus spaces (non-path) and newlines (used for 2D layout).

#### Execution semantics

Copied directly from the README, with some parts edited for Minyrinth:

> The source code consists of single-character instructions and is interpreted as a 2D grid. The instruction pointer starts at the first non-whitespace character in the file (in reading order) going right.
>
> Labyrinth is interpreted in a simple loop. At each step, the command under the instruction pointer is executed, then the new movement direction is determined, and then the instruction pointer moves one cell in that direction. The edges of the grid are not connected.
>
> The instruction pointer will generally follow "corridors" of instructions. Junctions can be used for non-trivial control flow. How the new movement direction is determined depends on the number of available steps (i.e. number of direct neighbours with known commands):
>
> - 4 neighbours: The top of the main stack is examined. If it's 0, keep moving straight ahead. If it's negative, turn left. If it's positive, turn right.
> - 3 neighbours: Do the same as for four neighbours, but if you hit the wall, reverse the direction. Hence, a T-junction hit from the side differentiates between 0 and non-zero. A T-junction hit from the bottom on the other hand sends negative/positive to the left/right whereas a 0 value reverses the direction.
> - 2 neighbours: The first rule here is, don't turn around. So if you came from one of the two directions, continue in the other direction. If this is not the case, but one of the two directions is straight ahead, follow that one (this can happen, for instance, at the start of the program in a corner).
> - 1 neighbour: Go towards the only available direction. Usually, this means you have hit a dead end and turn around on the spot (executing the command you turn around on only once).
> - 0 neighbours: Remain where you are without changing your direction. This can occur at the very start of the program.

### Challenge

Solve the halting problem for Minyrinth. Unlike Labyrinth which is Turing-complete, Minyrinth simulates a specific case of a [pushdown automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) whose halting problem is decidable.

For output, you can choose to

- output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
- use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Some hints can be found in CS Stack Exchange: [Decidability of halting problem for DPDAs with \$\epsilon\$-transitions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60052/105590), [Counter Machine (Halting Problem)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/105218/105590)

Answer (score 0):

## Plan my factory

"Factory games", such as Factorio, Mindustry, and Satisfactory are my favourite genre of video games, and the way I play them involve a lot of ratio calculations to make sure the factory is running as efficiently as possible.

Given a list of recipe specifications, and a desired production rate of an end product, output the necessary input rates of raw materials, where "raw material" is any ingredient that does not have a provided recipe.

For example:

Recipes:

```
[
    {
        name: "Iron Plate",
        time: 3.2,
        quantity: 1,
        input: [{
            name: "Iron Ore",
            quantity: 1
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "Copper Plate",
        time: 3.2,
        quantity: 1,
        input: [{
            name: "Copper Ore",
            quantity: 1
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "Iron Gear",
        time: 0.5,
        quantity: 1,
        input: [{
            name: "Iron Plate",
            quantity: 2
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "Automation Science Pack",
        time: 5,
        quantity: 1,
        input: [
            {
                name: "Iron Gear",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Copper Plate",
                quantity: 1
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Desired production rate:

```
{
    name: "Automation Science Pack",
    rate: 60
}
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        name: "Iron Ore",
        rate: 120
    },
    {
        name: "Copper Ore",
        rate: 60
    }
]
```

Both input and output may be any standard IO format that represents item names as strings and quantities/rates as integers.

### Testcases

TBA

### Sandbox

Is this a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8214#8214)?

Answer (score 0):

## OEIS A049190

your task is to print all numbers of this sequence.

is separated by newline, is separated by space or separated by comma.

the first few numbers are:

```
1, 3, 5, 59, 245, 2491, 235253, 127756731, 330567489269, 258479716298484155, 36823182192123209878050549, 25576412117054296344209353299113896379, 10994511204169842163496446583221775727830456269734123253
```

### How to get numbers of this sequence:

this is look and say but in binary and convert to decimal

## Meta

- How to clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

## Baloney Sandwich KOTH

Tags: [king-of-the-hill], [python]

### Introduction

In this King Of The Hill Challenge, your bots will be playing Baloney Sandwich.

#### How Baloney Sandwich is played

1. First, the entire deck is dealt equally to all players (EVERY BOT PLAYS; if there is more than 26 bots, it will be 2 decks mixed together).
2. Then, the player with the ace of spades goes first.
3. They play all of their aces

   - However! They could opt to "cheat" and instead play cards that are not aces, or mix and match aces with other cards.
4. Every other player has their `call_bs` (bs = Baloney Sandwich) method called after this play, in turn until a player returns `True`; if a player returns `True` then the cards played are "revealed".

   - Every player has their `bs_call_outcome` method to "reveal" the cards
   - If no player returns `True` but the player was lying, the `pb` method is called (pb = Peanut Butter)
5. Play continues with twos, threes, etc.; after kings, start over at aces

### Creating A Player

Your player should be in this format:

```python
class ExamplePlayer(AbstractBSPlayer):
    def __init__(self, hand: list[int]):
        super().__init__(hand)
        # Any necessary initialization goes here

    def call_bs(self, player_name: str, card_rank: int, number_of_cards: int) -> bool:
        """
        player_name is the name of the bot who just played
        The number of cards they played is number_of_cards
        The claimed rank is card_rank (1 is Ace; 11-13 are face cards)
        """
        # Magic decision maker
        return False # never calls "Baloney Sandwich"
        # return True would always call "Baloney Sandwich"
    
    def bs_call_outcome(self, player_name: str, caller_name: str, card_rank: int, cards: list[int], cheated: bool):
        """
        player_name is the name of the bot who just played
        caller_name is the name of the bot who called "Baloney Sandwich"
        The claimed rank is card_rank
        The cards they played is cards
        cheated is True if the player cheated
        """
        pass  # Couldn't care less
    
    def pb(self, player_name: str, card_rank: int, number_of_cards: int):
        """
        player_name is the name of the bot who just played
        The number of cards they played is number_of_cards
        The claimed rank is card_rank (1 is Ace; 11-13 are face cards)
        """
        pass # Couldn't care less

    def play_cards(self, card_rank: int) -> list[int]:
        """
        The rank you will claim to play is card_rank
        """
        # Magic decision maker
        return self.hand[0] # Always plays the first thing in hand
```

A player has access to the following instance variables:

- `self.store`: A dictionary that is empty by default. The only instance variable allowed to be written to.
- `self.hand`: A list of `int`s, each representing a card (1 is Ace, 11-13 are face cards)

#### Testing Your Player

The controller can be found at https://github.com/sethpeace/bs-koth. I apologize in advance that it is janky beyond comprehension.

### Rules

#### Runtime Disqualifications

- You must play at least one card every turn
- You can't play cards you dont have in your hand
- You can't take longer than one second to return from a function

#### Pre-runtime Disqualifications

- No reading or writing to controller, runtime, or other submissions (bots can't read them; you can if you feel like it)
- Only write to `self.store` instance variable

  - Other variables inside function scope are of course OK
- Don't design a bot to defend or support specific bots
- Bots can't use the same strategy as another bot
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply

Comment: This seems too similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48473/thats-bs-card-game

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms you are correct; thank you

Comment: It's cool to see some more KotHs being written though! If you have any ideas for ones that you're not sure are dupes, feel free to bring them up in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) to save the effort of having to write out a whole spec first.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms alright thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

## Implement xorshift128+

I don't have time to finish writing this draft at the moment.

Might also consider something like xoroshiro if it's more interesting to implement, but since xorshift128+ is so common it seems like a clearer choice.

(Possible idea: Given initial seed, determine number of iterations it'll take to get a certain random number with xorshift128+. It's not a CSPRNG, so there might be something more interesting than brute force.)

Answer (score 0):

[Chunk Sort a Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238329/chunk-sort-a-sequence)

Comment: use [tag:fastest-code] there are few questions with both tags.

Comment: time spent on what interpreter? can you say TIO?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena what if the interpreter is not on TIO?

Comment: You'd need many more test cases to get significant results with fastest-code. Also, using TIO for timing is a bad idea (I'm sure there's a post on meta about that, but I don't know exactly where).

Comment: @Arnauld [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/is-tio-acceptable-for-fastest-code-questions)

Comment: @Arnauld added more test cases

Answer (score 0):

## [Event scheduler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238199/100664)

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox. The challenge type is called [tag:fastest-code] here. It looks well-defined in general, but a few minor issues: 1) You don't really need restrictions in time complexity (the requirement 1) when submissions are competing for it. 2) Looks like the build instruction is linux only. If so, it should be clarified as such (along with dependencies like `cmake`).

Comment: FYI, language-specific challenges are discouraged here, and fastest-code without language restriction is usually done by measuring time on a single machine (often the challenge author's). (Not sure how to adapt this specific challenge to other languages, so I'd say it's fine in this case.) And unfortunately we're not like other competitive programming sites, and therefore have very few C++ users.

Comment: OK so would it be acceptable to submit a sample C++ code as guidance and open up to other languages?

Comment: @Bubbler Changed the terms of the challenge. Does it look better as it stands?

Comment: I mean, because of the nature of the task, it's near impossible to establish fair comparison across languages. Normally you'd feed input in a standardized format through STDIN and let the programs output through STDOUT, but 1e8 events would make I/O time way too significant. And not all languages have mt19937 implementation or seeding it like C++ does. So I was saying that limiting to C++ is fine here, though it won't get many answers on this site.

Comment: Hmm we could then open by classes like in boxing but per language here. Winner for C++, Java, Python, etc. And the IO is really not much - just generate a random sequence in memory and submit.

Answer (score 0):

## Radiate a prime checker into a sum program

Write a program or function that takes a number n and returns/print truthy if it is prime, and falsy otherwise. Additionally, if you remove 1 character of the source code, the program must now take a list of one or more numbers and return/print the sum. This must work for at least one character, and your score is however many characters that this does /not/ work for. Lowest score wins.

## meta:

let me know if i need to clarify anything etc
also: would it make sense to allow the programs to be the other way around (i.e. a sum checker where removing 1 character makes it a prime checker instead)? Just in case it could lead to a more interesting golf

Comment: It says "remove **or change** 1 character". By change, do you mean simply changing an arbitrary character to another arbitrary character, e.g. `abc -> axc`? If so, a lot of golfing languages will likely be able to make a trivial 0-score program where they simply change a 1-byte prime checker to a 1-byte sum command. That might not be a bad thing, per se, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @AaroneousMiller True, ill stick to just "remove". Wasn't sure of potential ramifications, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Quickly pour liquid nitrogen

I have a container of liquid nitrogen, but nothing to measure it with. I do have some containers, whose volumes I know, and I know how much I start with. My goal is to fill any container with a given amount of liquid nitrogen, with the fewest possible pours.

Importantly, liquid nitrogen boils away as I pour it. Every time I pour liquid nitrogen into a container, a milliliter is lost.

**Pouring mechanics:**

If I have two containers, `a` and `b`, and I pour `a` into `b`:

- If both are empty, nothing changes
- If `b`'s unused volume is greater than or equal to the volume of liquid nitrogen in `a`, `a` is emptied into `b`, and a milliliter boils away from `b`
- Otherwise, as much as possible is poured from `a` into `b`, and an additional milliliter is taken from `a` (so `b` will still be full)

If I have three containers, `x`, `y`, and `z`, they all have volumes of `25`, and they contain `25`, `10`, and `18` milliliters of liquid nitrogen respectively, here are some example pours (one after another, not indiviudual):

1. `x` into `y`: `y` is filled, and `x` is left with `9` milliliters
2. `y` into `z`: `z` is filled, and `y` is left with `1` milliliter
3. `z` into `x`: `x` remains full, `z` is left with `24` milliliters
4. `y` into `z`: `z` remains at `24` milliliters, `y` is emptied

(Note that in your input, not all containers will have the same volume)

**Task:**

Given a list of container sizes, where the first container is initiallyfull and the amount of liquid nitrogen you must measure out, return the minimum number of pours that would be needed to leave that much in any container.

You may assume volumes are non-negative integers, and the initial amount of liquid nitrogen will never be less than the amount you should end with. The actual sequence of pours you use doesn't matter, as long as you output the minimum possible count.

**Test cases:**

```
Containers          Target      Output

7, 4                3           5
12, 3, 3            4           2
100, 10, 8          84          6
8, 8                5           3
10, 0               8           2
100, 20, 20, 17     73          7
```

**Other:**

I don't think this is a good challenge after doing the test cases

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: @emanresuA You too!

Answer (score 0):

#### Tinla Resqua (Latin Square of rotated words)!

Based on this (currently closed) [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113028/words-created-by-permutations-of-a-7-letter-word-in-a-grid) on Puzzling, your task is to take a single word generate a valid 'latin square', not by permuting the letters in a word, but by rotating the word.

E.g. if one row was CENTURY then ENTURYC is a valid row, but ENTCTURY is not.

Also unlike some Latin Squares, no diagonal may contain repeated letters either.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | E | N | T | U | R | Y |
| R | Y | C | E | N | T | U |
| T | U | R | Y | C | E | N |
| E | N | T | U | R | Y | C |
| Y | C | E | N | T | U | R |
| U | R | Y | C | E | N | T |
| N | T | U | R | Y | C | E |

Is a valid grid.

[latin-square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-square) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: For even-length words, I think it is impossible to create such square by only rotating the word. At least it is surely true for length 2 and 4.

Comment: @bubbler then they could error or return null or similar?

Comment: That could work. (I'd make it more lenient and say "output something that can be distinguished from a valid solution".) Determining absence of solution is actually harder than that, because it's also impossible for 3. It seems to depend on the existence of solution to "toroidal n-queens problem".

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/220433), which states that such a square is possible exactly when the smallest prime factor is 5, which is equivalent to [n%6 being 1 or 5](https://oeis.org/A007310).

Comment: @bubbler very interesting

Answer (score 0):

## [Get all binary between a binary number and its reverse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238596/get-all-binary-between-a-binary-string-and-its-reverse)

Answer (score 0):

## [Return all letter counts as an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238533/66833)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## [Kolmogorov-simple numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239758/kolmogorov-simple-numbers)

Comment: Why not more flexible IO? Requiring a print seems pointless to me.

Comment: Seems like this would be better if the challenge was stated as "output the smallest number \$l\$ in \$n\$ bytes, such that \$l < \log_{256}(n + 1)\$". I agree with pxeger, it's a lot more simple to just use our standard I/O rules, and not worry about it

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

This was heavily inspired by the [donut.c](https://www.a1k0n.net/2011/07/20/donut-math.html) program

---

## Challenge:

You have to come up with a program that prints (in console) a shape that looks exactly like the shape of your code.

For example, if your code's shape looks like this:

```
    2343
3kf5
     3o*/f
   3%kt^7
```

then the output's shape should look like this:

```
    9I8b
&yt^
     )ph67
   {}fgh]
```

(the byte don't need to match, just the shape)

## Rules

- Empty programs/whitespace-only programs are not allowed.
- Your program should have more than 2 lines/statements of code.
- Each line should not be identical to every other line.
- All whitespace characters (space, tab,...) don't have to be identical.
- Whitespaces characters don't count towards the minimum bytes count.
- Your program's source code and the output should not be identical. It should be at least has one different character.
- The output should have at least two different bytes on one line.
- You should not use comments.

## Scoring criteria

- Longest code (in bytes) wins!
- If two same programs have the same byte count, the one with the most unique characters in the output wins!
- If two same programs have the same unique characters, the one with the most different characters in output compared to source code wins!

---

## Meta

- Does this question have any duplicates?
- My wording is bad, can you improve it?
- Is this question interesting? Fit within the rules of the site?

Comment: How will you tie-break solutions that change all characters from source to output, while having no duplicated characters in the output?

Comment: Are programs without any whitespace allowed?

Comment: [Please avoid requiring minimum scores](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928/43319).

Comment: [Please avoid cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/43319) like requiring printing in a console, which also [makes assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/43319) and [arbitrarily overrides the defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8065/43319). Instead, refer to the [default for code golf output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/43319).

Comment: I suggest changing "input" to "source code".

Comment: Can you confirm that [this](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@x0aO2yY/6poY6Bz/q3Wxi8ah3bmJSckoqSPa/AhgUAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") is an optimal answer (minimum allowed byte count changing all its characters while having no duplicates in the output) and that if I post this answer, I win? Note also that the source has no duplicated characters either, so that it won't help to add a rule for tie-breaking on unique characters in the source. Furthermore, code and output have no characters in common at all, preventing that as a tie-break too.

Comment: I think "longest code wins" is problematic. People can probably make it as long as they want.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the change to [tag:code-bowling]. Have a look at [the tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-bowling/info) for tips and warnings. Also, note that the maximum number of unique characters will be 1114112.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42017/66833), potentially a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

## [Repeat average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240070/repeat-average)

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge

You should write a program that has one in (your code in bytes) chance to output a 4 (could be a function that returns a 4). So if your code has 10 bytes, your code should have 1 in an 10 chance to print out a 4. Otherwise, output "finding my dice".

## Rules

- You can use whitespaces, comments or any unnecessary code to get to the number of bytes that you want.
- You shouldn't use any loopholes.

## Winning criteria

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wín!

Comment: What should the solution do in the n−1 out of n cases?

Comment: @Adám Do you mean when it doesn't print 4? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: Say my code is 10 bytes long and I run it 50 times. On average, 5 of those runs should print a 4. What should the remaining 45 runs do?

Comment: You phrasing sounds a lot like a program that prints is required. Please clarify if a function (e.g. taking a dummy argument) that returns 4 is allowed.

Comment: Are we allowed to embed unnecessary strings to reach a desired byte count?

Comment: @Adám Wouldn't that just make your score worse though?

Answer (score 0):

## [Check if the string is reshaped.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/239788/106959)

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you try to reword it?

Comment: @pxeger read examples carefully

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I did, but it's really not clear what you mean by "reshape"

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms `⍴` in APL.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I don't know APL, and you can't expect people solving the challenge to either. You need to explain what you mean by "reshape", in a way that people will be able to understand without a background in any particular language.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms ask to Adám.

Answer (score 0):

## Find duplicates, quickly

In this challenge, you'll be given a list of positive integers or non-empty alphabetical strings (your choice), and must return a list containing all duplicates. You must do this with the minimum time complexity you can, and as few bytes as possible.

**Task:**

Given a list of either positive integers or non-empty alphabetical (lower or uppercase, your choice) strings, return a list containing all duplicates. You may contain a duplicate value any number of times, so for the input `[a, b, b, c, d, d, d, d]`, any of `[b, d]`, `[b, d, d, d]`, `[b, b, d, d, d, d]`, or even `[b, b, b, b, d]` would be fine.

**Scoring:**

Scoring is by both average time complexity and bytes. A better time complexity will always beat an answer with a lower one, and byte count is a tie breaker. E.g., if there are two \$O(n^2)\$ answers, at 10 and 20 bytes, and an \$O(n\log{n})\$ answer at 140 bytes, it would rank higher than either of the others (until either a shorter \$n\log{n}\$ answer or an answer faster than \$n\log{n}\$ showed up).

As in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), this is per-language, so Vyxal and Vim, Charcoal and C, or Japt and Java are not competing.

Comment: But what if I don't know the time complexity of some operations in my compiler / interpreter? Some languages only define the correct output for certain operator without specify the time complexity. This could happen when some language provide a Map<> without specify if the Map<> is [TreeMap<>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [HashMap<>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Dumbo octopus flashing time [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

[Day 11 of this year's AoC](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/11) was about a grid of bioluminescent dumbo octopi. I'll try to explain how this works, click on the link for a better explanation.

You have a 10x10 grid of octopi which slowly gain energy and flash when fully charged. Each octopus has an energy level from 0 to 9:

```
5483143223
2745854711
5264556173
6141336146
6357385478
4167524645
2176841721
6882881134
4846848554
5283751526
```

The flashes and energy amounts can be modelled with steps. At each step:

- All octopi have their energy level increase by 1
- Then, any octopus with an energy level greater than 9 *flash*. When  an octopus flashes, it increments the energy levels of all octopi adjacent (orthogonally or diagonally) to it.
- The flashing repeats until no more octopi can flash. Then, all octopi that flashed during this step have their energy level reset to 0.

For example (stolen from AoC):

```
Before any steps:
11111
19991
19191
19991
11111

After step 1:
34543
40004
50005
40004
34543

After step 2:
45654
51115
61116
51115
45654
```

In step 1, the octopi with energy level 9 are all incremented to 10 and flash, all incrementing the octopus with energy level 1 (initially incremented to 2) in the center and causing it to flash as well.

The second part of the puzzle asks how long a configuration will take to have all octopi simultaneously flash in the same step. However, not all configurations will do this - some will fall into other cycles. Eventually, ***all*** of the configurations will repeat themselves, as there's only \$10^{10 \cdot 10 } = 10^{100}\$ possible configurations - still a huge amount, but finite.

Your challenge is to find a configuration that takes as many steps as possible to return to a configuration it's reached before, with more steps being better.

[People on reddit have been investigating this](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/re3dyf/2021_day_11_frequency_of_synchronous_octopi/), and the number to beat is [372886](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/re3dyf/comment/ho6s27x/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

### Meta

Is the explanation good, and should I bother with it?

Better examples?

Comment: Why is it not \$10^{100}\$ configurations? Also, it's not initially clear that an octopus increments for *each* adjacent flash.

Comment: @att Oops, made  a mistake  with #1 and I'll  try clear up #2

Comment: @att Better now?

Comment: Yeah, I think so

Answer (score 0):

#### Identify basic building blocks for new natural and programming language

(Based on [Invent new programming language and write Hello world in it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240385/invent-new-programming-language-and-write-hello-world-in-it), but re-phrased to gain more focus on answers).

There exists variety of different programming languages, also variety of natural languages.

If we could create new programming language, which in a turn would possess structure of natural language - what basic structures you would choose ?

one example of artificially constructed language is Toki Pona:

- https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona
- https://omniglot.com/language/phrases/tokipona.htm

It can be used as natural language, but not as a programming language.

One example of programming language is for loop - for example in C#:

`for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }`

If you want to express this kind of sentence in natural language - then you can use `'equals'` for `'='`, `'less than'` for `'<'` - but `scope begins` `('{')` and `scope ends` `('}')` is relatively long and difficult to express / pronounce.

What basic language structures you would propose for new language ?

Answer (score 0):

## Universal Command Sequence

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241047/universal-command-sequence)

Comment: Very related: [Shortest universal maze exit string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53310/20260)

Comment: I feel like answers to this will be very hard to test. Probably the golfiest way to do this, if it's valid, would be not to code anything with mazes, but just to produce some massive random-looking sequence of directions. If the length is a fast-enough growing function of `n`, with overwhelmingly high probability works on every maze for every `n`. Like, "output `3^3^3^n` in base 4".

Comment: @xnor This question is actually from a Russian math olympics problem :D that problem is to prove the existence of the sequence. The proof states that the sequence can be generated by following a certain rule (a certain rule of concatenating sequences, to be exact). And I think I do have written a testing code for it; see section "Test Code" (sorry but English isn't my mother tongue, but now I know it is called a "validator", isn't it?)

Comment: Ah yes I rembered, it's 1998 All-Russian Math Olympiad, Grade level 9, Day 1, Problem 4. Original problem is 8x8 grid, but the proof can be generalized to nxn.

Answer (score 0):

## [Identify a "reverse checkers" position](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240571/identify-a-reverse-checkers-position)

Answer (score 0):

## [Generate Fmbalbuena Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240985)

Comment: so both the second step and last step need to be true?

Comment: @Razetime 2nd and last step need to be true.

Comment: combine step 1 and step 2 into "Check if the number of digits is a multiple of 3", and change "`N`/`3` digits" to something like "`Length` / `3` digits" (to me "N/3" reads like the original number divided by 3).

Comment: "equals the last digits" → "equals the last digits modulus 10"

Comment: You should state clearly that having a digit count that isn't divisible by 3 is enough to make a number not be a Fmbalbuena number.

Comment: What is the goal of the challenge? [tag:decision-problem] for a single given number (I recommend that) or generating the [tag:sequence] up until a limit, or maybe the first n number, or "infinitely" spitting out more?

Answer (score 0):

## High throughput prime numbers

Answer (score 0):

## Wordle

The game [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) is quickly becoming popular.

The way the game works is as follows:

1. Players are trying to guess a 5 letter word
2. Players have six attempts to guess the word
3. After each attempt, the player is told:
   a. which letters are in the right place (index)
   b. which letters are in the word,  but in the wrong place
   c. which letters are not in the word at all

The aim of this challenge is to create a Wordle application, as follows:

1. On startup, the application reads from a dictionary of 5-letter words and selects one at random
2. The application then prompts for user input
3. On input:
   a. The application checks the input to ensure it is also a 5-letter word and in the dictionary. If it is not, the application returns any failure message and exits
   b. If the input matches the chosen word, the application returns any success message and exits
   c. Otherwise, the application checks the letters of the input against the letters of the word, and returns to the user an indicator for each letter of whether it is correct, misplaced, or incorrect. If a letter is repeated in the input, only the first occurrence is marked as correct/misplaced; the remaining occurrences are marked as incorrect *[sandbox qn: what happens if the actual word has repeated letters?]*
4. Steps 2 and 3 are repeated until the application aborts in step 3a or 3b; or the user has failed to guess the word a total of 6 times; at which point the application exits

### Sandbox

I am thinking of this as a code-golf challenge, but I wonder if there's another approach where people create the bot that's trying to solve the challenge, as well as the bot that's providing the challenge? Or something else? I'm not familiar with the other types of challenges to suggest something.

Comment: The hints wordle gives back are a little more complicated when a letter appears multiple times in the guess.  I still think there's a lot left to clear up here otherwise but that sort of edge case behavior is one thing that should be made clear.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, yes, that's why I put it in the sandbox!

Comment: Somone has played around and found out the repeated letter rules over on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wordle/comments/ry49ne/illustration_of_what_happens_when_your_guess_has/).

Comment: IMHO in its current form it contains too many tasks in one challenge. Maybe limit the challenge just to step 3 or even just step 3c?

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: @pajonk I agree it's probably too complicated as-is for a [code-golf] challenge. I don't want to reduce it to just a simple "which letters are in the correct place" challenge though - I feel that's not interesting enough. What about a different scoring system - perhaps a variant of [king-of-the-hill], where you're either trying to create a bot that can solve Wordle quickly; or a bot that picks words to avoid being solved easily - and they're pitted against each other. Would that be more interesting?

Answer (score 0):

## Generate Matching Regexes

Write a program that takes two lists of strings and generates a javascript regex that fully matches all the strings in the first list and matches none of the strings in the second list.

To be specific when for all stings in the first list `str.match(\[your-output]\)` must produce a match for the full string and for all strings in the second list `str.match(\[your-output]\)` must produce no matches.

### Scoring

Your score is the average length of the regexes you produce not the length of your program. Your regexes should be tested against this file: https://pastebin.com/9iNZvGJC. Take the file in blocks of 20 lines and run your program with the first ten lines to match and the second ten to not match. Average the lengths of your program's output for all of the blocks in the file. This is your score.

### Rules

- Do not output the `\` for the regex

Comment: I'm guessing this is a Sandbox for [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230870/66833) closed challenge, and that you're aiming to improve the existing one? I'd suggest clarifying the scoring system, I'm not fully sure how exactly it works?

Comment: Yes it is. Could you clarify what you find confusing about the scoring system?

Comment: "Take the file in blocks of 20 lines and run your program with the first ten lines to match and the second ten to not match." Seems like it would be simpler to just provide the lines to match and the lines to not match, rather than doing the line splitting bit

Comment: You would have to split it into blocks anyway so that doesn't really seem easier?

Answer (score 0):

## Help Bob split his apples

Bob has a lot of apples, and he wants to split his apples with his friends evenly. (Including Bob.) However, every \$k\$th friend already has a lot of apples and does not need apples. Bob, however, is kind so he gives each \$k\$th friend the number of apples the friend already gives floor divided by three.

Given the input format below, a number \$k\$, and a number \$a\$ for the number of apples, output the number of apples that each person receives.

## Test Cases

```
[0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 12] 3 100 => [10, 9, 26, 9, 9, 15, 9, 9, 4]
```

Comment: Could you try to clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

## Move the next greater number, with fewest fails to take everything

Your task is to move the next greater number, with fewest fails to take everything

A fail counts if a step is the lower number (not counting equal)

The starting point is the top left corner

Example:

```
1234
```

Can do like this

```
>>>
```

Because moves to right, the next number is greater than previous

But

```
124
435
```

Is impossible so the fewest fails are:

```
>>v<<
```

`1` > `2` > `4` > `5` < `3` > `4`

So this has 1 fail

### Test cases:

The output is not exact, there are multiple possible solutions

Input:

```
123
245
175
```

Output:

```
>>vv<<^>
```

Input:

```
123456789
```

Output:

```
>>>>>>>>
```

Input:

```
987654321
```

Output:

```
>>>>>>>>
```

Input:

```
123
456
789
```

Output:

```
>>vv<<^>
```

Input:

```
123456789
987654321
123456789
```

Output:

```
>>>>>>>>v<<<<<<<<v>>>>>>>>
```

## Meta:

- Any feedback?

Comment: I like the idea but I think the explanation could include the definition of a "fail".

Comment: @Wezl-yizl Added

Answer (score 0):

## Euler Irregular Primes

Your challenge is to find all [Euler Irregular Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers#Euler_irregular_primes) (A prime p is Euler-irregular if it divides an Euler number E(2n) with 0<2n<p−1) under `n`.

### Scoring

Your goal is to use the least amount of bytes.

Comment: welcome to this website ! challenges should be self contained, so while the link is good, you should Also include a definition of euler irregular primes

Comment: Could you provide some test cases and define "storage" clearly?

Answer (score 0):

## Deterministic oozes

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

#### Task

Output the next generation of the input.

These conversions happen if there is food `.` or `:` next to them:

```
"o" → "O"
"O" → "8"
"8" → "oo"
```

^ These are called oozes.

#### Rules for eating

- The food should disappear if it gets eaten.
- If there is a single food `.`, with oozes on both sides, the left one eats it.
- If there is a double food `:`, with oozes on both sides, both eat one.
- If there is a double food `:` with only one ooz beside it, the ooz eats the entire food and advances 2 generations.
- A food with no oozes on the either side, stays the same.
- Spaces between oozes should be preserved.

#### Scoring

Number of bytes, shortest code wins!

#### Test Cases

```
"o. o" → "O o"
"oooo.8" → "oooO8"
"8:8" → "oooo"
":8" → "Oo"
"8:" → "oO"
"o:o.o" → "O8o"
"ooo" → "ooo"
"o.o.o" → "OOo"
"o:8:o" → "OoOO"
" .  o o 8." → " .  o o oo"
```

### Meta:

- Tags?
- Clear?

Comment: There's a lot still missing here.  It seems like most the challenge has to be guessed from a handful of test cases.

Comment: @WheatWizard ok ill add more test cases tomorrow.

Comment: No that is the opposite of what I am saying.  You need to specify the challenge not just add more test cases.

Comment: The challenge should be completely understandable with the test cases removed.

Comment: @WheatWizard ok i see, will do that tomorrow

Comment: Having multiple generations happen at a time seems contrary to "output the next generation"

Comment: Suggested testcase: "o:o.o"

Comment: Will the input have leading/trailing spaces? How to handle them? Also, the `o:8:o` test-case is not covered by your specs (or anything like `.o.`).

Answer (score 0):

## Approximate Euler's Number

Euler's number (e) is one of the most well-known mathematical constants, with a simple way to approximate it. All you have to do is repeatedly generate a random number between 0 and 1, and add it to an accumulator. Record how many times you have to do this for the accumulator to exceed 1. If you do this over and over again, the average of all the times it takes will approximate Euler's number.

### Your task

Write a program that, given a number of iterations as input, approximates Euler's number using the above method and prints the result.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins. However, if the language you are using does not include a random number builtin, you may exclude from your byte count the code required to import it. For example, if you're writing a Python program to do this, you may assume the `random` module is already imported.

### Example implementation (ungolfed)

```
import random
acc = 0
res = []
for x in range(int(input())):
    while acc < 1:
        acc += random.random()
    res.append(acc)
    acc = 0
total = 0
for x in res:
    total += x
print(total / len(res))
```

Comment: This looks like it's probably [unobservable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228). You also [need to specify](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909) how "random" is defined: can programs use a biased RNG (which will inevitably produce an inaccurate approximation)?

Comment: @pxeger Good point. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: IMO the interesting part of this is never going to be the random number generation, but the calculation based on them. You could just have challenges accept an input of a list of numbers, presuming them to be random, and give the approximation calculated if that list were the source of random numbers. So an input of `[random.random() for _ in range(10000)]` will produce about `2.72`, but an input of `[0] * 10000` will produce some completely wrong output

Comment: Also, your code is missing a parenthesis on line 4, and outputs \$ e / 2 \$, not \$ e \$.

Comment: @pxeger I know the RNG is boring, whcih is why it's excluded from the byte count. Sorry about the bugs, I'm fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

## Count the ways to transform (3)

Your input is an infinite matrix (2d array) of nonneagtive integers where a finite area of the matrix contains nonzero integers. For example:

\begin{matrix}
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdot^{\cdot^\cdot} \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdot^{\cdot^\cdot} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}

A semi-continuous transformation of this matrix is a rearranging of elements that preserves immediate neighbors. For example, we can swap the \$2\$ in the bottom left, and the \$1\$ in the top left corner.

\begin{matrix}
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdot^{\cdot^\cdot} \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdot^{\cdot^\cdot} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}

This is fine, because every number has the same neighborhood counts. That is, we can make a sorted list of numbers and their neighbors, and verify the they are the same:

\begin{matrix}
\text{Number} & \text{Neighbors} \\
0 & 0,0,0,1 \\
0 & 0,0,0,1 \\
0 & 0,0,0,2 \\
0 & 0,0,0,2 \\
0 & 0,0,0,3 \\
0 & 0,0,0,3 \\
0 & 0,0,0,3 \\
0 & 0,0,0,4 \\
0 & 0,0,0,6 \\
0 & 0,0,0,6 \\
0 & 0,0,1,4 \\
0 & 0,0,2,5 \\
0 & 0,0,4,6 \\
1 & 0,0,0,3 \\
2 & 0,0,0,3 \\
3 & 0,0,3,6 \\
3 & 0,1,2,5 \\
4 & 0,0,3,5 \\
5 & 0,0,3,4 \\
6 & 0,0,0,3 \\
\end{matrix}

(we ignore zeros that have 4 zeros next them, since there are always infinitely many)

## TODO: Add example where non-semi-continuous transformation changes the neighborhood counts.

To clarify, semi-continuity is a property of a transformation on some specific matrix.

Your code will take an infinite matrix as input and output the number of (unique) semi-continuous transformations. Two transformations are different if the output is different. So for example swapping two identical numbers is the same as the identity transform (doing nothing). Also, since it's an infinite grid, simply translating the pattern is the same as doing nothing. You can assume the output number will always be finite.

Or in other words: Your code will take an infinite matrix and return the number of matrices with those dimensions that have the same neighbor-list.

Input can be in any reasonable format. You can decide if your input has to have some amount zero-padding or if you always take a square matrix, etc.

## Meta

Is this more interesting than version 2?

Comment: not sure what being infinite adds to the challenge since all that changes is that translations do nothing

Comment: If the non-zero portions form multiple disconnected segments with more than one \$0\$ separating them the result can be infinite.  For example if the finite portion is entirely within \$1,0,0,2\$ then you can just move the two non-zero values as far apart as you wish.

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes, that's what I meant with "You can assume the output number will always be finite"

Answer (score 0):

## Alternate indexing

## Task

(To do.)

## Test Cases

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] => [[1, 4], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]]
[[1, 1, 1]] => [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[]] => [[]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ragged Matrix

A ragged matrix, is a matrix that has a different number of elements in each row. Your challenge is to write a program in any favorable language to find the indices of all occurrences of target in the ragged matrix.

## Input:

A list of ragged lists (can be empty) of positive integers and a target range e.g. `56-26`. The target range, given 2 positive integers. For languages that do not support this type of list, you can input it as a string representation

You may assume that `a<=b`

## Output:

If a number in the ragged list is within the range or equal to `a` or equal to `b`, output the index of the ragged list then the index of the number in that ragged list e.g. `0 4` - The `0` is the first ragged list in the input and the `4` is the index of the number in the first ragged list

## Test cases:

```
[[[1,3,2,32,19],[19,2,48,19],[],[9,35,4],[3,19]],19-53]
->
[[0,3],[0,4],[1,0],[1,2],[1,3],[3,1],[4,1]]

[[[1,2,3,2],[],[7,9,2,1,4]],2-2]
->
[[0,1],[0,3],[2,2]]
```

You can choose to follow the output format above or output it in the following as well:

```
[[[1,3,2,32,19],[19,2,48,19],[],[9,35,4],[3,19]],19-53]
->
0 3 0 4 1 0 1 2 1 3 3 1 4 1
```

0-based and 1-based indexing is allowed

You can output your answers in any way as long as it is distinguishable what the indexes of the number and matrix are

## Tags:

code-golf

matrix

ragged-list

Comment: Please consider adding tags below the title (refer to the [template](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2130/55372)). Please also consider loosening the input criteria (e.g. allowing also inputting `a` and `b` as integers with assumption that `a<=b`). You may also explicitly state that both 1- and 0- indexing is ok.

Comment: are my edits ok now pajonk? i have changed it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

## Truncatable Primes

A left-truncatable prime is a prime number and when the first digit is removed continuously, the result is always prime.

A right-truncatable prime is a prime number and when the last digit is removed continuously, the result is always prime.

If the integer is only a left-truncatable prime, return `left`

If the integer is only a right-truncatable prime, return `right`

Otherwise, return `False`

## Test cases

```
9137 -> left
9137, 137, 37 and 7 are all prime
```

```
5939 -> right
5939, 593, 59 and 5 are all prime
```

```
139 -> False
1 and 9 are non-prime, so 139 cannot be truncatable from either way
```

```
103 -> False
It contains a 0 digit, which is not prime(even though 103 and 3 are primes)
```

You may assume that the input will never be both left and right truncatable, so an integer such as `5` will not appear in the input (it is prime and single digit so it is counted as both)

You are allowed to print `False` as `0` and `left` as `2` and `right` as `1`

OR

`left` as `1` and `right` as `2`

Otherwise, you are allowed to use any 3 distinct 3 values/string representation of `left`, `right` and `False`

## Tags:

primes

classification

Comment: Rather than those specific strings, I would recommend letting people choose their own four distinct values

Comment: Also, I think there’s a tag for classification challenges

Comment: I'd recommend allowing some inputs to be both left and right-truncatable because it makes the challenge more exciting, but that's all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

## D'Hondt method

the D'Hondt method is a method for allocating seats in parliaments.

Given the Amount of representatives the district you're calculating for is given, and the total amount of voters, and a map or dictionary of every party alongside all the votes they got, you will be asked to give the amount of representatives each party will get from that electoral district as a map or dictionary depending on your language, or as a list/array of whose first index will contain of the party name as a string or char[], then the second the number of representatives as a number (the type is all fine as long as it doesn't have any decimals and is not negative, and their string conversions are something like this: f123 -> "123")

the algorithm: https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-dhondt-method
another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method#Procedure

like as output those are all fine:

```kotlin
return mapOf(
    "Party A" to 4
    "Party B" to 3
)
```

or

```kotlin
return arrayOf(
    "Party A",  "1",
    "Party B",  "2"
)
```

you can even give Array as an output as long as you clarify how to get proper values from it somewhere in the answer (in easy terms of course)
like:

```kotlin
arrayOf(
    "Party A" to 4
    "Party B" to 8
)
```

and you can post a snippet like

```kotlin
for(value in output)
{
    if(value::class == Int::class) println(value as Int)
    if(value::class == String::class) println(value as String)
}
```

The Input will be similiar as such:

- mutableMap<String, Int>
- - "Partyname":  Amount of votes it got
- Amount of Voters in that district
- Amount of representatives to be assigned to the parliament from that district

The Output will be something like:

- mutableMap<String, Int>
- - "Partyname": Amount of representatives it got
    or
- mutableList<String, String>
- - "Partyname": amount of representatives it got in a comprehensible form
- - - Like: [PartyA, 5, PartyB, 10, PartyC, 15]
      or
- List<List<String, String>
- - Like: [ [PartyA, 5], [PartyB, 10], [PartyC, 15] ]

Those are not strict rules and just a general remind that as long as the input/output is comprehensible it is fine

Comment: Challenges must be self-contained so you should describe the method directly in the post instead of relying on links. I'd recommend deferring to our [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/92901) rather than spending so much text describing possible formats (you've said yourself that there are no strict rules). Lastly, avoid using language-specific terms/concepts like `mutableMap<String, Int>`.

Comment: Actually, looks like this challenge has already been done: [It's election time!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50694/92901) Hopefully the advice in my previous comment will be helpful for future posts.

Comment: will sure keep this in mind, also, thanks for showing me the actual post about this.

Comment: should I delete this

Comment: I think so, yes. Unfortunately it's a duplicate of the earlier challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Tips for golfing in Seriously

I am looking for tips to code in this golfing language [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), and was wondering what some of the best/subtle ways for golfing this language is. Thx in advance!

Comment: Not much of a corpus left to learn from by example...

Answer (score 0):

## Solve Rubik's Clock

Posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242274/solve-rubiks-clock).

Answer (score 0):

## Where is the line

Given a grid consisting of `+` and a constant \$m\$, change all the `+` to `x`, where the center of the `+` is above the graph \$y=mx\$.
Considering:

- The origin is the bottom-left corner of bottom-left `+`.
- One unit is the width=height of a plus
- The center of the bottom-left plus is located in \$(0.5, 0.5)\$

## Rules

- Input can be given as an iterable, string or a binary matrix.
- Instead of a grid, input can also be the \$height\$ and the \$width\$ of the matrix.
- Output must consist of `+` and `x`
- [Standard Loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

## Example

```
[In]:
++
++
0

[Out]:
xx
xx

[In]:
++
++
1

[Out]:
xx
x+

[In]:
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
2

[Out]:
xx+++
xx+++
x++++
x++++
+++++
```

## Meta

Did I explain it good enough?

Answer (score 0):

## The Futuristic Battle Royale

After a five-year hiatus, I am interested in extending [The Futuristic Gun Duel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104896/the-futuristic-gun-duel) to a battle royale format. If this is not a bad idea, I will propose some rules and then start coding using some JS framework that uses WebWorkers. The primary motivation is that this should significantly change the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

## Iterate over pairs of nonnegative integers

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

Find and implement an iteration over the set of pairs of nonnegative integers (\$\mathbb N_0^2\$).

```
(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) ...
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) ...
(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) ...
(3, 0) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) ...
...
```

For example, diagonalization:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 0), ...
```

You must specify which iteration your answer uses. You must specify if your answer is 0 or 1-indexed. Your code must be *deterministic*.

This is a [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge. You may...

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ values.
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the value for \$n\$.
- Take no input and output values indefinitely.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the smallest code as measured in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Answer (score 0):

## Loopless unending program

Your task is simple: Make a program in your language of choice that never exits. However, you are forbidden to use any looping constructs (`for`, `while`, etc). in your source. You may use any other instruction in your language to accomplish this goal.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Comment: Can you define what a "looping construct" is? Also, you might run into (this issue)[https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/107310] with langs that just don't loop the same way.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output)

Comment: I think "without looping" is not a well-defined requirement. You could instead require programs to *block forever*, which is observable at the OS level, although I think that then isn't very interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ragged index of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243329/ragged-index-of)

Comment: Many golflangs have a builtin for this, for example [Vyxal's `Þḟ`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuG4nyIsIiIsIjVcblsxLCAyLCBbMywgNCwgWzYsIDVdLCA3XV0iXQ==) and [Jelly's `œi`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/aUCfaSMdYJ9pExzQ2Nvbo5EzT//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## Will the dominoes topple?

Your input contains a list of positive integers representing the height of a row of dominoes. As many of us know, when you have a row of dominoes and push the first one, the rest will topple in a chain reaction. But if the next domino is too big, it will not fall. This depends on the shape of the domino, so in addition to the list, your program will also receive a positive rational number \$r\$, so that domino \$n\$ will topple domino \$n+1\$ iff \$h_n\cdot r>h_{n+1}\$, where \$h_n\$ is the height of a domino.

Your task is to decide if all the dominoes topple or if the chain reaction stops before the end.

Your input is a non-empty list of positive integers (the height of the dominoes) and the rational number \$r\$.

You must use exact (integer) math, fp math is not allowed (though languages like Javascript and C can assume that the integer types are bigints).

Use standard [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) output rules. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code per language wins.

## Examples

```
[1,2,3], 5/2 -> True
[1,2,3], 3/2 -> False
[23,11,5,1], 1/2 -> True
[1,3,9,29], 10/3 -> True
[5,10,9,11], 2/1 -> False
[1,1], 1/1 -> False
[1], 1/1 -> True
```

Answer (score 0):

## Output up to n sets of n characters randomly

Given a positive integer n>1, output a random number of n-character strings, ranging from 1 to n strings.

### Rules

- Each string must differ from eachother by at least 1 char
- Each string must be n chars long
- Other than that, output strings do not have to be consistent in any way
- However, our strings must be clearly delimited
- A "random number" of strings means that each time the program is run with input n, non-deterministically, either 0, 1, 2, 3... up to n strings will be output
- For smaller inputs, each possible number of strings should be displayed within a reasonable number of trials (to avoid cheesy solutions where one number gets chosen with probability ~1)

### Examples

These are examples of valid outputs:

```
input => output
2 => af 4b
2 => 12 22
2 => ba
3 => WTF TL; VMB
3 => 0l3
3 => 04t <V<
3 => bop bAm
3 => AAA,AAB,AAC
3 => 
000
001
002
4 =>
w la
    
a,v 
 i  
3 => [tip, wor, kf3]
```

These would be invalid:

```
input => output
explanation of invalidity

2 => Ca Sa Da
too many strings output for this input

2 => asd sd mo
too many chars in a string for this input

3 => a Bad
too few chars in a string for this input

4 => 1234567890123456
strings are not clearly delimited

3 => 1   2   3   
strings are not clearly delimited

3 => A,B,BCD
strings are not clearly delimited

3 => CO CO LA
two or more strings are identical
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Meta

Is this too trivial? Also, can anything be phrased clearer (including the title)?

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge: Create a program that plays the game of the goose

In this golfing challenge, write a program that simulates [the game of the goose.](http://www-cs.canisius.edu/%7Esalley/SCA/Games/goose.html) If you don't know how it works, here's a rough explanation of it:

The game takes place on a grid of 63 cells:
[image: grid]

Each turn, the first player **rolls** two dice and will **advance* (number rolled) cells. Then the second player will roll two dice and do the same as player 1.

If a player lands on a **goose**, he will move **again** by the same number of cells.

If a player lands on the **bridge**, he will move to cell **12**.

If a player lands in the **tavern**, he will skip **2 turns**.

If a player's first rolls are **6 & 3**, he will go to cell **26**.

If a player lands in the **well** or the **prison**, he will **wait** until the other player lands in the same cell. Then the player goes to the other player's former cell.

If a player lands in the **maze**, he will go to cell **30**.

If a player's first rolls are 4 & 5, he will go to cell 53.

If a player lands on **death**, he will go to the **start**.

### Implementing it

#### Randomness

The dice rolls represent random numbers; the programming language you use needs to have a way to output (Any output method) and a way to generate random numbers.

#### Output

The program should output each iteration of the game; Each turn, it should output the player's position. Like this:

```
Turn 1: 16, 4
```

The first and second numbers represent each player respectively. When a player wins or after a certain maximum number of turns, the program will stop.

### General Rules

1. The player must be able to win.
2. Making up your programming language is allowed, provided you made an interpreter available to the public for your programming language.
3. Don't exploit standard loopholes.
4. Make sure your code runs in at most 10 seconds.

### Recommendations

1. You should include a link to a website (for example https://tio.run) so that your code can be easily run.
2. If you're using a compiled language, say which compiler you're using.

**It's code golf, so the shortest code wins!**

Comment: I have no idea why the grid didn't work. I tried to fix it in this edit.

Comment: I'm too lazy to recreate the grid so here is an image of the grid.

Comment: You should specify what kind of input/output the answers should have. For example, should the programs output the positions of the players every round until one player wins?

Answer (score 0):

### Weekday celebration with Doomsday

With the help of the [Doomsday rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) you can always calculate the day of the week for any date given. It includes any digit year.

Your code should determine which day of the week will be on the Valentine's Day of the given year.

The input is an integer representing the year, and the output is a number representing the day (1 - monday, 2 - tuesday, etc).

#### Test cases

> 2001 -> 3
> 1916 -> 1
> 41373 -> 7
> 312631 -> 1
> 71254065 -> 6
> 512836172 -> 5
> -2735263 -> 3

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Answer (score 0):

[Mountain mapper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242777/mountain-mapper)

Answer (score 0):

## Uncountably long chain of subsets

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

A chain of subsets (a chain from now on) is a sequence of sets, so that every set is a (strict) superset of every preceding set. For example, here is a chain of length 3:

\$\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,4,5\}\subset\{1,2,3,4,5\}\$

Chains can also be infinitely long. Here is a countably infinite chain:

\$\{2\}\subset\{2,4\}\subset\{2,4,8\}\subset\{2,4,8,16\}\subset\ldots\subset\{2,4,8,16,32,...\}\$

Your task is to make an **uncountably** infinite chain, consisting of sets of positive numbers.

Your gut reaction might be that this is impossible. But it's not. For example, consider the real numbers. We can define them as Dedekind cuts (meaning every real number is defined as the set of rational numbers that are smaller than it). Next we can associate every rational number with a positive integer. Now, under the standard ordering of the real numbers, we have a chain of subsets of the positive integers that is uncountably long.

Now that you've picked your favorite uncountably long chain of subsets of the positive integers, it's time to make a program that encodes it.

Your program will recieve two natural numbers. Your program will simply tell whether the first natural number appears before or at the same time as the second one in the chain. Or in other words: for inputs \$a\$ and \$b\$ return true iff \$b\in S\Rightarrow a\in S\$ for all sets \$S\$ in the chain. Your chain must contain every positive integer (however, this doesn't mean that it must contain the set of positive integers).

Bonus points if you achieve a cardinality different from \$2^{\aleph_0}\$

## Edit:

Probably not gonna post this challenge as is, because of a rather trivial solution (lexicographic ordering)

Answer (score 0):

## Grid Aligned (Quad?) Linked List

### Fluff

I was recently thinking about 2-dimensional linked lists, and realized that they could potentially become unaligned to a grid, unlike a singly linked list. To combat that, I need a program that checks if a quad-list is grid aligned or not, and it needs to be done as short as possible.

### Challenge

Given a quad linked-list, return true or false (or any other 2 consistent values) whether or not the 2d list is grid aligned.

### Input

Since linked lists can be implemented a variety of different ways in different languages, I'll keep the input format fairly simple. An input consists of tuples (or 4-lists, you can decide) which contain indices that refer to the input. Each tuple contains the indices of the node above, below, left, and right in that order. For nodes where not all directions are connected, the value will be -1.

Note: "above", "below", "left", "right" should be connected in that direction, but may not necessarily do so.

### Examples

[(-1, 1, -1, -1), (0, -1, -1, -1)] -> true

```
0
|
1
```

[(-1, 1, -1, 3), (0, -1, -1, 2), (-1, -1, -1, -1), (-1, 2, 0, -1)] -> true

```
0---3
|   v
1 > 2
```

[(-1, 1, -1, 2), (0, -1, -1, 2), (0, -1, 1, -1)] -> false

```
0
| \
1--2
```

[(-1, 1, -1, -1), (-1, 2, -1, -1), (-1, -1, -1, 3), (4, -1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 0, -1)] -> false

```
0 < 4
v   ^
1   |
v   |
2 > 3
```

[(0, -1, -1, -1)] -> false

```
0
^
0
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

## [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242969/107299)

Comment: Question: is Python a valid language for this challenge?

Comment: At first I wasn't going to allow other languages, but I think I can whip up a command line interface ;)

Comment: @StackMeterPlus added a protocol

Comment: you can clear this post now, by adding the link of the question here and deleting everything else

Answer (score 0):

## Determine if a number is base n heavy

Given a positive integer \$n\$ and a base number \$b\$, determine if the number is heavy in that base. A number is heavy if when converted to base \$b\$, has at least \$ \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor \$ \$b-1\$s on one end. (The left or right.)

### Examples

When we convert 100 to base 2 (binary), we get

```
1100100
```

\$\log_{10}(100) = 2\$, and there are at least 2 ones (the max number in the base) on one end (the left side).

### Scoring

Shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases

Coming soon.

---

Feedback?

Comment: What do you mean by \$\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor b - 1 \$? Is this base \$n\$ or base \$b\$?

Comment: The base 10 logarithm feels a bit arbitrary. This also means that there are no heavy numbers if \$b>9\$

Answer (score 0):

## Draw a battery indicator

#### [Posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243337/draw-a-battery-indicator)

Answer (score 0):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

## Implement Scordle

#### Background

TODO: Explain what [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) and [Scordle](https://scoredle.com/) are

#### Challenge

Your task is to implement a modified version of Scordle with lists of numbers.

The input contains the following:

- The possible numbers `1` to `n` that can be contained in a guess (think of this like there are 26 letters that can be used in regular Wordle)
- The number sequence that represents the correct answer (assume that the answer contains only numbers between `1` and `n`)
- Optional: the length `l` (at least 1) of the correct answer
- The list (length 1 to 6) of the guesses (unlike Wordle, the list doesn't have to end in the correct answer, even if the length of the list is less than 6). Assume all guesses are valid.

Output a list of numbers that represent the number of possible number sequences that conform to all the clues at and before that point.

#### Example

Let's say that the answer is `[3,2,1]` and the possible numbers are from `1` to `n=3`. Before any guesses, there are \$3^3=27\$ possible number sequences that can potentially be the answer:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Let's say that the list of guesses is:

```
[[2,1,3],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[3,2,1]]
```

After the first guess `[2,1,3]`, all of them are yellow. Based on these clues, the remaining possible sequences are listed below:

```
[1, 3, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Because there are 2 possibilities remaining, the first element in the output list will be 2.

In the second guess `[2,2,2]`, the middle `2` will be green while the other two `2`'s are black. This eliminates `[1,3,2]` and leaves the only possibility `[3,2,1]`. So the second element in the output list will be a `1`.

Any subsequent guesses will not affect the number of possibilities, so for the rest of the guesses, put `1` in the output list.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in byte count wins!

#### Test Cases (TODO)

```
answer, n, list of guesses, l
--> list of possibilities
--------------------------------
[3,2,1], 3, [[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[3,2,1]], 3
--> [2,1,1,1]
```

## Meta

- Suggestions for tags?
- I haven't put in the **Background** yet, but for people who already know what Wordle and Scordle are, is the task clear?
- Suggested test cases?
- Should I make it so that the guesses always have to end in the correct answer?

Comment: I think your list of guesses needs `[2,1,3]` in the first place.

Comment: @pajonk "(unlike Wordle, the list doesn't have to end in the correct answer, even if the length of the list is less than 6)". Should I make it so that it has to end in the correct answer?

Comment: After the fix the part "After the first guess [1,2,3], all of them are yellow" is not true (2 is green). Re: ending in correct answer - I don't have a strong opinion either way.

Comment: @pajonk oops I meant to keep [2,1,3] as the first guess, not [1,2,3]. As for ending in the correct answer, I think I'll just keep it as is, because if it always end in the correct answer, the last element of the output list will always be 1, but if it doesn't always end in the correct answer, the last element is not always 1, which is more interesting (I think?) .

Answer (score 0):

## Is it irrational?

Your task is to make a program that decides if a real number is irrational or not. As stated, this is obviously impossible, so instead we will use the following definition:

`p` is your program, which takes in a decimal expansion of a number (list of integers), and returns 0 or 1. If `x` is an irrational number, then \$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p(x[:n])=1\$, and if `x` is rational the limit superior has to be 0. \$x[:n]\$ means the truncated decimal expansion, which is just the first `n` digits after the decimal point (the integer component obviously doesn't change the irrationality).

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins. Also, standard [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules apply, so instead of outputting 0 or 1, you can output true,false, "Yes", "no", etc. As we know, \$0.999...=1\$, so you can assume that the decimal expansion doesn't contain a trail of repeating 9s. Instead of decimal, you can use binary.

Answer (score 0):

## Pick the best seat in a vehicle

We have eight seats in a vehicle, represented by numbers:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

Two people get in. First person will pick the seat X. Number X will be inputted to the program. The second person will pick the furthest seat from the first person. Output (or return, if a function) the seat number which person B will take.

All seats are on the same elevation, and can be represented with two integers in a coordinate grid. The difference between two adjacent seats (horizontally or vertically) is the same between every seat.

For example, if person A chose seat number 7, person B will sit on 1.

**1 <= X <= 8**

All possible combinations: (the output for specific input is shown directly underneath the input)
Input:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Output:

```
8   8   5   5   4   4   1   1
```

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162337/seats-in-a-finnish-cinema

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf and thanks for using the Sandbox! Could you please add some more test-cases? Please also specify what distance metric are you looking for (I suppose [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)). You may also explicitly specify what the output is (the seat for person B I presume).

Comment: Can we take input `0 <= X <= 7` instead?

Comment: @pxeger That would not make sense as in real life you will never find seats labeled starting from zero

Comment: As the input is constrained between 1 and 8, I suggest providing output for all inputs in the test-case section.

Answer (score 0):

## All empty cells are neighbours

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

### Task

Given dimensions of a 2D grid \$n>1,m>1\$, output the size (number od cells) of the minimal connected region, so that every empty cell is its neighbour.

Cells are neighbouring (or connected) when they share a side, so no diagonal connections.

### Background

When putting together jigsaw puzzles with my son, I always try to reach a single connected region of solved pieces such that empty places have at least one piece to connect to. This way he can test every loose piece one place after another, and always find a spot to fit it.

### Details

- You may take \$n\$ and \$m\$ in any reasonable format and output corresponding region size.
- You may also output as an infinite sequence, as long as you use a bijection of  \$\{2,3,\ldots\}\times\{2,3,\ldots\}\$ into \$\mathbb{N}\$ (and provide it in your answer).

### Test cases

```
n=2, m=3 -> 3
Example grid (you don't need to output that):
###
...
n=3, m=4 -> 4
....
####
....
n=4, m=4 -> 8
....
####
####
....
n=4, m=5 -> 9
....
####
...#
####
....
n=2, m>1 -> m
n=3, m>1 -> m
```

---

### Meta

- Better title?
- Better tags?
- Is the output as infinite sequence well defined?
- Any mistakes in the examples?

Comment: `n=2, m=3` -> 2 (`.#. \ .#.`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Convert JSON object of directories to list of paths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246845)

Comment: What's the scoring criterion? Does the shortest code win? If so, then please specify the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: May we expect the input to be non-empty?

Comment: Can we take the input in other formats (I'm thinking in favour of languages without native JSON support)? E.g. as a ragged named list, list of nested tuples etc?

Comment: JSON typically doesn't have order defined. And some standard doesn't allow duplicate keys while some others support duplicate keys. For example `{"a":{"b":{}},"a":{"c":{}}}` could be a valid JSON in some standard.

Comment: @pajonk Shouldn't JSON be string? And I believe most language should support string at least any languages that support ragged list.

Comment: @tsh, yeah, I was thinking about built-in JSON parsing to other structure. Some languages may have advantage from it, while other will be stuck to string-parsing. But that was just a suggestion for OP to decide.

Comment: @pajonk The input is non-empty, in the sense that there will always be a JSON object, but it could be `{}`. In this case, the output must be empty or a newline.

Comment: @pajonk I was thinking to allow as input either a string, a dictionary, or a list of tuples, each tuple contains the name and the value (which is a list of tuples). 
What you think? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @tsh Since I would allow dictionary as a valid input format, and since the JSON object represents a directory structure, the input won't have duplicate keys.

Comment: I would allow the use of basic JSON parsing libraries in languages that don't have built in JSON support

Comment: @MatteoC. Yes, I think allowing reasonable equivalents to JSON seems fine. Also, with this relaxed rule I would not allow "basic JSON parsing libraries" as it may be ambiguous what to qualify as "basic".

Comment: I strongly discourage too narrow output format (at least a list of directories should be acceptable IMO).

Answer (score 0):

## Finding an element in an array

Please tell me whether this challenge has been created or is in the sandbox! I tried searching for it, but with thousands of pages, I easily could have missed one.

### Your task:

Given an input of an array, and a certain element found in that array, output the coordinates of the element. Output a falsey value if the element cannot be found in the array.

### Rules:

- The array will be made of single (non-space) ASCII characters. The element to be found in the array can be input either before or after the array

```
e3R5     e
p10-     e3R5
.v!x     p10-
0>3v     .v!x
e        0>3v
```

- You must output the coordinates of the element found in the list. The top left corner is (0,0)

```
(0,0)  (1,0)  (2,0)
(0,1)  (1,1)  (2,1)
(0,2)  (1,2)  (2,2)
(0,3)  (1,3)  (2,3)
```

- Keep the x and y coordinates separate. `(0,1)` and `0 1` and `0,1` are all valid outputs, but `01` is not.
- You can assume there will not be more than one of the specified element in the array, but other elements may appear more than once.
- This challenge is case-sensitive!

### Test Cases:

```
e3R5
p10-
.v!x
0>3v
e
```

Result:(0,0)

```
43T0*x
\@.2,c
''b%gP
5qQ}#m
q
```

Result:(1,3)

```
mW(
iMz
EA/
$"t
a]:
7
```

Result: (falsey)

```
-c2?08r,TZTj
"^9LT^*`LFu2
^"~l6-PiyPo8
,f=[aOv50ZnO
`
```

Result: (7,2)

Answer (score 0):

[Sandbox overflow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245414/sandbox-overflow)

Comment: It seems awfully similar to your chained compound challenge: here you simply add slashes instead of spaces, and dots instead of spaces, and draw only one "circle".

Comment: hmm ill try to change that. didnt realise it was so similar :/ @ophact

Answer (score 0):

Given a current page number (`p`), pages to show (`s`), and max pages (`m`), create the classic pagination, marking the current page as active (`*`) and using `...`'s for any outside the range.

For example:

```
p = 1, s = 5, m = 15
```

Should output:

```
1* 2 3 4 5 ... 15
```

Or

```
p = 7, s = 5, m = 15
```

should output

```
1 ... 5 6 7* 8 9 ... 15
```

and

```
p = 2, s = 5, m = 4
```

Should output

```
1 2* 3 4
```

It can be assumed that pages to show (`s`) is always odd, so the active page is often in the middle of the set of numbers.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for using the Sandbox! I feel this challenge may be a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/243701/55372

Comment: Oh yes... it has some confusion over what the correct output should be for the edge cases as well. Ah well!

Answer (score 0):

## Integer divisors of a decimal number

The input is a decimal number larger than zero, given in decimal form. You can use any unambiguous printable character(s) to enclose or separate a possible repeating part in the input, such as `0._3_`, `0.(3)` or `0.(3` for \${0.\overline{3}}\$ to represent an exact third.

The output is the pair of the smallest integer dividend and divisor that give the exact value represented by the input. The output format doesn't matter, `1/3`, `1 3` and `(1,0b011)` are all valid for an input value representing an exact third.
Examples:

```
Input:  1
Output: 1 / 1

Input:  0.(3)
Output: 1 / 3

Input:  1.234
Output: 617 / 500

Input:  1.1(3)
Output: 17 / 15

Input:  3.454(54)
Output: 38 / 11

Input:  3.14159
Output: 314159 / 100000

Input:  3.(142857)
Output: 22 / 7

Input:  12.345(6789)
Output: 10287037 / 833250

Input:  9.(9)
Output: 10 / 1
```

### Reference implementation in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

It does \$12.345\overline{6789} = \frac{12345}{1000} + \frac{6789}{9999*1000} = \frac{123444444}{9999000} = \frac{10287037}{833250}\$

```python
def greatest_common_denominator(a, b):
	while b:
		a, b = b, a%b
	return a

def r(inp):
	x, _, repeating = inp.rstrip(')').partition('(')
	x = x.split('.')
	dividend = int(''.join(x))
	divisor = 10**(len(x[1]) if len(x) == 2 else 0)
	if repeating:
		repeating_nines = 10**len(repeating) - 1;
		dividend = int(repeating) + dividend*repeating_nines
		divisor *= repeating_nines
	d = greatest_common_denominator(dividend, divisor)
	return dividend//d, divisor//d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwEDw3X7EXZDsEt86DPlA/gBMfgFCUEqc1SpzIdqGo6reHdUkDKhKXze7MzmRsd59u1@qk70tZwdbIwknr8te2aVqdl1K3jdKFaw0tItiwVTD52Klawga7iYdgDZsIiptNMDHS7Y2GIgi8l6FKd15wiCCPwMgOvZXeogAJbqwzqqOEEca7wjjlVKspQQAVuHPgtquVo4R7pFTvCsOUZzGChL@1StMDGzjbGqTELAxpLRF/Fi8MVAXngcF6DTHI2kqYoQDxMY0/xjjkWmlpByMvHRkGdyAecPcqyK@FW7hw4ZXhIPMZwzX8Ib3Xfxd/sY1gcGHjVV@o6fSHxb6v8FcWAwIhJBDBjNOEBYLHSYpV@CHhaZbSLPWdSEW2xC8VabzI5rgZ8yTN6P18sWTBklOsaDQ8iH/SzvjDV@RRd3u3Ajjak3@lb5g87d0ZPp5gioVwjNMUjoaGWsbGPdZ/AQ)

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count wins!

Comment: I recommend the title "Integers divided to obtain a decimal number"

Comment: Unfortunately this is a duplicate of [Convert a repeated decimal to a fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/convert-a-repeated-decimal-to-a-fraction).

Answer (score 0):

## Construct integers from `1`, `-`, and `(`

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness/245876#245876), I used only `1`, `-`, and `(` to construct any integer (although `(` is technically unnecessary) in TI-Basic. Your task is to make a program or function that takes an integer (or a different convenient format to represent it) as input and output the shortest possible string made from `1`, `-`, and `(` that will evaluate to the integer in TI-Basic. If there are multiple possible outputs, then choose the one with the least amount of `(`. If there are still multiple left, then any one of them is valid as an output.

Some things to note:

- `-` is the subtraction symbol, not the negative sign.
- TI-Basic automatically closes all `(` at the end.
- `(` can also be used for implied multiplication (e.g. `11(11` is 121)

### Rules

- It should work for numbers from `-128` to `127`.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

### Test cases

```
Input    | Possible Output

-128     | 1-(11-1-1-(1-11(11
-124     | 1-111-11-1-1-1
-44      | 11(1-1-1-1-1-1
-5       | 1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-3       | 1-1-1-1-1
-1       | 1-1-1
0        | 1-1
1        | 1
2        | 1-(1-1-1
3        | 1-(1-1-1-1
5        | 11-1-1-1-1-1-1
8        | 11-1-1-1
10       | 11-1
11       | 11
14       | 11-(1-1-1-1-1
18       | 11-1-1-1-(1-11
19       | 11-1-1-(1-11
21       | 11-(1-11
22       | 11-(1-11-1
33       | 11-11(1-1-1-1
43       | 11-(1-11-11-11
78       | 111-11-11-11
123      | 111-(1-11-1-1
127      | 11-1-1-1-1-(1-11(11
```

If your output is different from the one listed, then it should have the same length and the same amount of `(`.

### Meta

- Is anything unclear?
- Are any of the outputs for the test cases incorrect?

Comment: Are there any inputs for which there is more than one `(` in the output? If that's false, maybe specifying that at most one `(` is permissible would make the rules simpler? Or that's just me?

Comment: @pajonk 127 becomes `11-1-1-1-1-(1-11(11` and -128 becomes `1-(11-1-1-(1-11(11`. I suppose I will add those as test cases.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification.

Comment: But 127 can be done with `1-(-111-11-1-1-1-1`? Any nonnegative integer can be made with `1-(1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-...` with at most one `(`, and any negative integer can be made with `-1-1-1-1-1-1-...` with no `(`s.

Comment: @pxeger As stated in the beginning, `-` is the subtraction symbol, not the negative sign (TI-Basic makes a distinction between the two). The main priority is to make the shortest possible string with `1`, `-`, and `(` to represent the number, then to have it have the least amount of `(` possible.

Comment: Maybe you should either move "shortest" to the "Rules" section, or move "If there are multiple possible outputs, then choose the one with the least amount of (. " tie-breaker into the header. Currently, it placed in different places and may be confuse.

Answer (score 0):

### Generate a clue for an arbitrary MultiSoft URL

Here is the program that will verify your output (transcripted into javascript, and modified for my own ease)

[image: Sheet of paper containing a small program in python. Javascript version below]

```js
let s = '';
const a = 'your output here'
for(const i = 1; i < a.length; i+=1){
  if (a[i] % 2 === a[i-1] % 2) {
    s = `${s}${Math.max(a[i], a[i-1])}`;
  }
}
if ('your program input' === `www.multisoft.se/${s}`){
   return true;
}
```

Where you're given 'your program input', which will look like *[www.multisoft.se/9109382911](http://www.multisoft.se/9109382911)* and you need to generate an `a` ('your output here') that generates that URL.

#### Test cases:

`// TODO make test cases`

Answer (score 0):

### Wordle but Harder

If you've been online in the last year, you probably know the rules of Wordle. I was implementing a (very bad) Wordle algorithm, when I thought of another game:

### Task

One 5-letter word from wordle's answer list is randomly selected. Your task is to guess the word.

Each failed guess gives you one piece of information - the amount of letters in your guess that are also in the word.

For example, if the answer was `hello` and you guessed `loser`, you would get `2`, because 2 of your letters are in the answer. Conversely, if the answer was `loser` and you guessed `hello`, you would get `3`, as 3 of the letters in your guess are in the answer.

### Scoring

Each guess must be made within 10 seconds. Separate categories for lowest average and lowest worst-case scenario.

Comment: You may want to address in your challenge at least some of the comments from your closed post in main site https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245995/55372

Answer (score 0):

## Draw my shower curtain

I got a shower curtain and it looks cool, so today you get to draw it.

### But how do we do this?

I'm glad you asked.

#### Part 1: the shape

[image: circles]

The image shows a blue, red, and green circle. This is a subsection of the pattern. The actual pattern of circles can be imagined by placing a circle of radius 4 at (8i, 8j) and (8k + 4, 8l + 4) for all (i, j, k, l) in the integers.

[image: sectors]

This image shows the three circles from the first image, but with two sectors coloured in. These sectors are defined as the area in at least two circles, or the area in a circle centred at (8i, 8j) and in on at (8k + 4, 8l + 4), for (i, j, k, l) in the integers. I would provide a closed form for this, but I don't know one.

[image: more circles and sectors]

The above image shows more circles and sectors. In this image, you can begin to see how the pattern fills an infinite grid. For this challenge, you will take two integers as input and output a grid with that many of the pattern on each side. For example, this (specifically the intersections between two circles because I was too lazy):

[image: (3, 1) pattern]

is the output for (3, 1), and this (again I didn't mark the sectors because there were too many of them):

[image: (2, 2) pattern]

is the output for (2, 2).

As well as this, your image must be at least 800 pixels on each side.

#### Part 2: the color

[image: shades of grey: #0B, #22, #37, #4E, #66, #7F, #98, #B3, #CF and #EB]

The above shows some examples of shades of grey. All of them have the values of their red, blue and green component set to be the same. For your program, you must use all 256 possible shades of grey, with a non-zero chance of each occurring. You may not use any other colours than these.

Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins.

### NBs

You may assume both numbers are greater than 0.

You can take width or height first (examples take width first), but say which in your answer.

You are allowed to be +/- 0.1% off.

### Meta

Is this well specified?

Anything to change?

Comment: 1. What is to be "coloured" with the 256 shades of gray? The circles, the areas, both? What if there are less circles/areas than 256? Nevertheless, I suggest just letting the golfers to choose two distinct colours for background and objects; or three for background, circles and areas. 2. Could you please add at least one test-case that will fully comply with the specs?

Comment: Ok - on hiatus now, but will fix this later.

Answer (score 0):

## Heapify a List into a Binary Max Heap

Given a list of integers, write the shortest program or function that will heapify the list into a binary max-heap, and return the heap as a list of integers.

#### Additional Resources

- [Wikipedia: Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)
- [Rosetta Code: Heapify from the Heapsort algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Heapsort)

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- [Input and output can be in any reasonable format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)

Comment: Wouldn't sorting the list produce a heapified list too?

Comment: [Banning built-ins may not be a good idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/55372). [See also here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16673/55372).

Answer (score 0):

## Make a PDF look scanned

###### META: This challenge still needs more work, including some examples - if you already have suggestions and hints feel free to post them, but due to the nature of popularity contests I definitely want to discuss it again when I added the missing part.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Do you know the situation where you have to print some document, scan it and send the scan back? Let's automate that!
Your task is making a program that, given some input, makes it believably look like it was scanned.

A few people have done that before (links see [1](https://www.scanyourpdf.com/) [2](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31083432) [3](https://lookscanned.io/)) which inspired this challenge, but they all still look too uniform and pristine in my opinion.

Here some examples of the test file, a real scan and the output of (**TODO:** use one of these tools):

**TODO:** add examples of scan artifacts, compare real scan with examples.

## Details

- Validity Criterion: The input and output are raster images of any resolution (they should have the same resolution).
- For simplicity you can assume that both the input and output are grayscale images.
- You can assume that the input - no matter the resolution - has roughly the size of an A4 or Letter page.
- You should run your program on the test image below, and include it in your submission using `<img src="[image ]" width="400" alt="processed" />` (**TODO:** determine exact format), but you can also include other examples to illustrate the inner workings.
- You are encouraged to explain how your program processes the image.

**TODO:** Add test image.

Comment: IMHO, It's going to be difficult to specify well, but sincerely: good luck. I think it might be worth adding some suggested requirements (see [comment below your link 2](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31088861)).

Comment: Thanks:) I intend to add some images that actually show examples of artifacts like the ones you mentioned (I'm planning to actually make some prints/scans). But only as suggestions, as in my experience for this kind of challenge compulsive requirements really must be measurable objectively to work well. And thanks for your input, I'll let you know if/when I update the draft!

Answer (score 0):

## Multiples Game

Given an array of divisors `A`, loop `n` from 1 to infinity and do one of the following:

- If `n` is divisible by an even number of divisors of `A`, print out `n`
- If `n` is divisible by an odd number of divisor(s) of `A`, print out `*` (clap)

### Examples

Input:

A = [3, 5]

Output:

```
1
2
*
4
*
*
7
8
*
*
11
*
13
14
15
16
17
*
19
...
```

---

Input:

A = [2, 3, 5]

Output:

```
1
*
*
*
*
6
7
*
*
10
11
12
13
*
15
*
17
18
19
...
```

---

Input:

A = [3, 6]

Output:

```
1
2
*
4
5
6
7
8
*
10
11
12
13
14
*
16
17
18
19
...
```

### Rules

- Fetching outer sources are forbidden
- UTF-8 encoding
- A newline count as 1 byte (UNIX newline)
- The answer with the least bytes wins

Answer (score 0):

## [Shift a string gradually](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246556/shift-a-string-gradually)

Comment: Surely the output for the first test case should be `bdf`.

Comment: @chunes fixed..

Comment: I suggest adding a test case that requires wrapping.

Comment: @chunes implemented

Comment: Suggested test cases of length other than 3. How to treat empty string?

Comment: @pajonk done, i hope i didn't write the wrong result

Comment: Last test case output should be "bdfhjlm" right?

Comment: @ophact fixed it

Comment: Wait actually it's bdfhjln

Comment: @ophact fixed it

Comment: You should remove all but the title, which should be linked to the posted challenge. Then delete this post.

Comment: @Adám fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Infinite Candle Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246767/66833)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really two challenges (generate sequence, draw colours). Please let me know!

Comment: This really does seem like two challenges. I recommend just requiring answers to output the number sequence, as it does make the challenge more accessible to languages that do not have any form of graphical output. That being said, if it is going to be a purely sequence challenge: Is floating point precision error allowed? Or does the whole decimal number have to be outputted? Or are we outputting as a list of pairs `(numerator, denominator)`? I also recommend including the first 100 terms or so of this sequence in the challenge body somewhere, as to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: If it's going to be graphical output: How should the colors be displayed (square, circle, any shape that you choose, etc.)?

Comment: If it's graphical output, you should provide hex codes or screenshots of the first few colors in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I'll reduce this to just outputting the sequence. I'll add more info as well.

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

## Split given integer into a given number of integers, each within given bounds

### Input variables:

(Names are just examples, they don't need to be named like this)

- `GrandTotal` - integer to divide
- `SplitCount` - number of output integers required
- `UpperLimit` - highest valid value for any one output integer
- `LowerLimit` - lowest valid value for any one output integer

There must be `SplitCount` values returned, each of which is a uniformly random integer between `UpperLimit` and `LowerLimit` (your language's RNG is fine), the sum of which is `GrandTotal`.

Also, the order of the output matters: 5,8,7 is not an equal set to 5,7,8. Both outputs must be equally likely if either is possible. 
<sub>(This does mean that output where all three integers are the same is less likely output to one where all three are different: Given `GrandTotal`=6, `SplitCount`=3, `UpperLimit`=4, `LowerLimit`=1, a set including 1, 2 and 3 can appear in 6 different configurations, while a set of all 2s can only appear in one, making it 6 times as likely that *one of* the varied sets will appear, rather than the set of 3 2s.)</sub>

### Assumptions:

Any input variables should work, assuming that the following is true

1. `UpperLimit` * `SplitCount` >= `GrandTotal`
2. `LowerLimit` * `SplitCount` <= `GrandTotal`
3. all input variables are positive integers.

### Sample in-out range

| GrandTotal | SplitCount | UpperLimit | LowerLimit | Possible Output Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 | 10 | 2 | 10,1;9,2 |
| 8 | 3 | 11 | 2 | 2,3,3;3,2,3;3,3,2;2,2,4;2,4,2;4,2,2 |
| 13 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 8,5;7,6;6,7;5,8 |
| 16 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 8,8 |
| 16 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 10,6;9,7;8,8;7,9;6,10 |
| 16 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 4,4,4,4 |

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question that specifies language, but couldn't see anything in the help that said it shouldn't...

Comment: Language-specific challenges are technically [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8790/96039), but make sure that this challenge utilizes some language-specific feature, and that it's not just arbitrarily restricting to this one language. I don't know enough about SQL to fully judge this challenge, so you will have to make your own judgement call on this.

Comment: @AidenChow Practically, it's SQL because I have a yucky version of this I'm using at the moment in a SQL environment, and I want to see just how un-yucky it can get, but it did seem like a reasonably valid code-golf idea based on my limited experience of this stack, so thought I'd give it a bash.
Given that there are some limitations on the specific built-in functions you have in SQL that other languages don't share, opening up the languages to other ones would be less useful *for me*...

Comment: @AidenChow also I'd be very interested to see if anyone has really simple/fast ways of adding other language-code in, like a shortcut CLR function (a concept I definitely need to become more familiar with...)

Comment: Code golf isn't really the place to go to if you are looking for "un-yucky" code; code golfers will do any atrocity you can think of in order to shorten the length of their code, most times sacrificing readability and actually making "yuckier" code in most cases. Though if you are fine with that, then I don't see anything inherently wrong with this challenge. You could definitely add some test cases though.

Comment: Actually now that I'm looking at it, there are some things wrong with this post. First, you need to indicate what the winning criterion is, whether that be [tag:code-golf], [tag:code-challenge], or something else entirely; this is required for ALL code golf challenges. Second, as I stated in my comment above, you definitely should add some test cases, so that people attempting this challenge can easily test their code. Third, it is recommended that you add a short worked example for an example test case. Just a short explanation would suffice.

Comment: Oh wait sorry, I didn't read the challenge fully; it's random, so there are no set test cases. In that case, just include an example input and a possible output, and a short explanation.

Comment: @AidenChow better or worse?

Comment: It's better, though I fear that with a scoring system with that many rules, there is bound to be some ambiguity that's going to arise when people actually start attempting the challenge and scoring their programs. I don't know enough about this particular language though, so I will leave it up to others to give a better judgement on this. My gut feeling is that there are just way too many rules for scoring; I haven't seen a scoring system in a challenge with quite as many rules as this before.

Comment: Also, it is pretty standard to include the tags you are going to apply to this challenge when you are going to post it to the main website. You can add a tag like so: `[tag:(tag name)]`. With a complex scoring system like your challenge, I think you may want to add the [tag:code-challenge] or maybe the [tag:atomic-code-golf] tag (I'm not too sure how applicable this tag is to your challenge, though; as I said, I'm not entirely familiar with SQL).

Comment: @AidenChow thanks, was wondering how to add that.

Comment: Good as a language-agnostic solution?

Comment: You may also like to add `[tag:random]`. Also, consider specifying what kind of randomness are you looking for (be it uniform, any other or leave it to the golfers).

Answer (score 0):

## Draw the Location's Flag

Take as input the latitude-longitude coordinates of a location on Earth, and return a flag that corresponds to that location. You may return any official flag that is at the level of a country or smaller. For example, if the location was `40.712775, -74.005973`, you may return the flag of the USA, the New York state flag, or the flag of New York City, but you can't return the UN flag.

### Rules

The outputted flag must be at least 50 pixels in its shortest direction (or be vector graphics/some other scalable image).

Internet data IS allowed in this challenge.

Areas not officially controlled by any country are undefined behavior. This includes Antarctica, Bir Tawil, and international waters.

Any flag returned must be an official flag that currently corresponds to that location. For example, you cannot return the flag of the British Empire for countries that used to be its territories.

In cases where control is disputed (including South Sudan, eastern Ukraine...) you may output any country that has a claim.

This is a code golf challenge, so shortest code wins.

Standard I/O rules apply. Examples would include a list/tuple of two numbers, a Location class, a vector, or Mathematica's GeoPosition.

All flags must be recognizable as the flag they are.

For flags with differing sides (like Paraguay), you may return only one face.

For non-rectangular flags, you may pad the other area with any color distinct from the primary color of the flag.

Comment: This is a bit hard tho...

Comment: It's supposed to be quite difficult. I imagine some programming languages have builtins to fetch the flags of a country (mathematica in particular), which would make things easier, but other languages will still struggle. I have considered changing it to be a code challenge where your score is increased (a bad thing here) if you miss some, but you don't have to get every country right.

Comment: I mean, it would be sort of unfair, right? To non-mathematica languages?

Comment: Yes and no. It would likely have a far shorter solution (but some other languages might also have these builtins, so they might be shorter), but its solution isn't going to be short either. There isn't a quick way I know of to check if a point is in a country, it will just help with drawing the flags.

Comment: I think I can do it in 37 bytes in Mathematica, but I'm not 100% sure it works all the time and it could potentially be shorter. My guess is other languages will need quite a bit more, but it still feels doable.

Comment: Yeah, but I think Mathematica has way too big an advantage at that.

Comment: It has a very large advantage for sure, but it's mostly a language-by-language competition. I've been wondering about methods to make it a little closer, but the goal isn't for Mathematica to compete against everything else, just like the goal isn't for Vyxal to compete against Python. I feel like on most challenges, if they are simple, a golflang wins, and if they are complicated, some Mathematica-esque language with a lot of builtins wins. This question is just more towards the complicated side compared to most code golf problems.

Comment: this does actually seem to me to be a somewhat interesting challenge, although I do feel that it is kinda two challenges in one: 1) given an arbitrary latitude/longitude coordinate, find some governmental entity that claims control of that location and 2) given that governmental entity, output its flag. it might be better breaking this into two, or selecting only one of them

Answer (score 0):

## [Irradiated Polyglots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247469/irradiated-polyglots)

[radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening) [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Answer (score 0):

## [Alternating sums of multidimensional arrays](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247398)

Answer (score 0):

## Quickly approximate the square root of a float

---

As in like, constant-time and almost instant, but off by a lot. No time for looping here. This is going to take a lot of work, since I'm going to make an emulated CPU which will allow more precise timing.

Answer (score 0):

## Desmosian Music

Create a script that takes in `notes` as `numbers` and `note lengths` as `decimals`.

You do **not** have to accept rest notes.

For instance, when given `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,0.5]]` you should return a desmos **code** that plots:

```
      -  <== 3
  ----   <== 2
--       <== 1
```

In this case it can be:

`\left\{x>0:\left\{x<2:1,\left\{x<6:2,\left\{x<7:3\right\}\right\}\right\}\right\}`

Scale the note lengths to fit entirely inside the graph.

This is [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf) and I appreciate desmos answers.

Comment: What’s the winning criteria? code-golf? Metagolf?

Comment: Probably best to explain the output. Does it need to be ascii art? A drawn graph? Desmos code? Could you provide an example of passing code?

Answer (score 0):

## Can we do it with an 89?

This was originally meant to be a Puzzling Challenge:

> ## Can we do it with an 89?
>
> `89` is my favorite number. Your task is to make 1~100 using only **one `89`**. Operations allowed are:
>
> - Factorial (`3! = 6`)
> - Parenthesis (`(3!)! = 6! = 720`)
> - Double Factorial (`4!! = 4*2 = 8`)
> - Square Root (`sqrt(9) = 3`)
> - Floor and Ceiling (`floor(3.5) = 3` and `ceil(3.5)=4`)
> - Negation (`-3 = well, -3, duh`)
>
> Note that `4!! = 4*2 and not (4!)!`

Your task is to output the equation given a number **greater than 1** (no longer restricted to be less than 100), inclusive.

## Meta:

- Should this be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
- Or should we aim to end with the shortest equation?
- Or should we aim for a shorter run time?
- Could this be 3 challenges?
- Or should I ask for code that outputs the shortest equation?

Answer (score 0):

## Good Rectangles and Evil Numbers

This is meant to be a Puzzling Challenge:

> ## Good Rectangles and Evil Numbers - Integrated
>
> Original: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116168/good-rectangles-and-evil-numbers
>
> ### Good Rectangle
>
> We define a *good rectangle* with base \$ x \$ as a rectangle in which \$ 
>                                                                          rac lw = x \$ where \$ l \$ is the length of the rectangle and \$ w \$ is the width of the rectangle.
>
> ### Tiling
>
> This is simply to **clarify**. There should be no problem if you ignore this section, but I would like the question to be robust.
>
> We define a tiling of a group of shapes onto another shape as a way to place the group of shapes such that:
>
> - The shapes do not overlap
> - The group of shapes covers the entire target shape
> - The target shape covers the entire group of shape
>
> (The latter two combined is equivalent such that the union of all shapes in the group is congruent to the target shape)
>
> ### Good Numbers
>
> We define a positive integer as a *good number* in base \$ x \$ if it is possible to *tile* that many *good rectangles* of base \$ x \$ (not necessarily of the same size) onto a square of any side length.
>
> ### Evil Numbers
>
> We define an *evil number* as a positive integer that is not a *good number* in that base.
>
> ...

Your Task: Given a number as the base \$ x \$ and a number as the number of rectangles \$ n \$, assuming that \$ n \$ is not an evil number in base \$ x \$, graphically output a tiling with \$ n \$ good rectangles in base \$ x \$.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Answer (score 0):

```
--\/--
--/\--
```

## Morse Tangles: ASCII Art

Given a word (with only letters, case insensitive), say `SOS`:

- Change the word into Morse code, in this case, `... --- ...`
- Change dots to parallel bars and dashes to tangles.

Output the result as ASCII art:

```
------  \/\/\/  ------
------  /\/\/\  ------
```

Note that the spaces are two characters wide. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Morse Code Chart:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2223/4507/files/morse-chart_grande.png?v=1501447409

Comment: Please, add a morse code table to the post for reference and provide some more test-cases. Please consider changing overline `¯` to a dash `-` as it's outside of ASCII range and that may exclude some languages from participating. I also suggest changing underscores to `-` for more golfing opportunities and removing the spaces between characters in the final tangle.

Comment: Done @pajonk ..

Comment: IMHO the Morse code table is short enough to be posted verbatim in the question (e.g. as a code block for easy copying) to make the question self-contained. Also, again, please add some more test-cases.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Tapes, Pointers, And sub-tapes: BrainFuck+

---

In this challenge we make an interpreter for a subset of BrainFuck+.

As with BrainFuck we start with the tape `[0]` and pointer at index `0`.

---

### BrainFuck+ Simplified: Commands

---

#### + and -

---

Update the current cell, as in BrainFuck.

---

```
++
```

=>

```
[2]
 ^
```

---

```
--+--++
```

=>

```
[-1]
  ^
```

(There exists no wrap around)

---

#### < and >

---

Update the pointer, as in BrainFuck.

---

`>`

=>

```
[0,0]
   ^
```

An attempt to go right at the rightmost point of a tape creates a cell with value `0` at the right.

---

```
++>+>++>-
```

=>

```
[2,1,2,-1]
        ^
```

---

```
++<+
```

=>

```
[1,2]
 ^
```

An attempt to go left at the leftmost point of a tape creates a cell with value `0` at the left.

---

#### v and ^

---

```
v
```

=>

```
[[0]]
  ^
```

An attempt to go down a numerical value overrides the cell with the empty subtape `[0]`.

---

```
>+<v+>-^>
```

=>

```
[[1,-1],1]
        ^
```

`^` exits the subtape.

---

```
v>^v
```

=>

```
[[0,0]]
  ^
```

An attempt to go down a subtape will enter the subtape at index `0`.

---

```
^
```

=>

```
Program Termination
```

An attempt to exit the main tape terminates the program. Otherwise the program must run completely.

---

#### Revisiting + and -

---

```
v^+
```

=>

```
Program Termination
```

An attempt to increment or decrement a list will fail and terminate the program. However no error will be raised.

---

#### Other characters...

---

...will not appear.

---

## Your Task:

---

Make a Simplified BrainFuck+ Interpreter. This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

---

## Test Cases

---

See above.

---

Comment: I like this concept a lot, but it could stand to be reorganized a bit for ease of reading, but thats' just my opinion.

Comment: @thejonymyster how specfically

Comment: IMO: Could summarize the whole feature-set up front, rather than introducing each feature one at a time. `+-<>` on their own are simple enough to have a sentence or two for, maybe some small examples alongside the explanations for `^v` and how they interact with `<>`, and then some more complex test cases all lined up in a single code block at the end. Also, the line breaks are bulky and not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting `n`th character of FizzBuzz**

I was inspired by the challenge to output FizzBuzz as fast as possible. I have written and optimized some code to the degree that it computed the `10^1000000`th character of FizzBuzz within 5 minutes (it's `"7"`). (Not the 10^1000000th line, this is the 10^1000000th **character**, and I don't mean 1000000, I really mean 10^1000000). See [here](https://github.com/leijurv/reverse-fizzbuzz/). I'm not sure how the challenge would work, perhaps it could be "how fast can you extract the `n`th digit of FizzBuzz, where `n` is a random number with a million digits"? Or perhaps a simple king of the hill for "what's the furthest power of ten index you can compute"? I wonder if someone can up that to `10^10000000`?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219009/efficient-bytewise-fizzbuzz

Comment: Thanks! But, that is just for the shortest code, rather than the most performant, or the highest character index computed. I commented my approach anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

## Rational numbers

---

### Challenge

Every rational numbers (can be written in a fraction form \$a / b\$ ( \$a\$,\$b\$ are integers)) can be represent as a periodic, repeating decimal number.

For example, \$1 / 3\$ is \$0.3333333333333333...\$, so we represent it as \$0.(3)\$. Another example, \$3227 / 555\$ is \$5.8144144144...\$ so we represent it as \$5.8(144)\$.

Your task is, given a fraction \$a / b\$, print out its periodic, repeating decimal number,

### Input/Output

- Input/Output can be taken in any resonable format, containing the fraction.

Testcase:

```
5/2 -> 2.5(0)
1/3 -> 0.(3)
3227/555 -> 5.8(144)
557/495 -> 1.1(25)
35/17 -> 2.(0588235294117647)
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so so shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Comment: dupe of [Fraction to Exact Decimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89215/fraction-to-exact-decimal)

Answer (score 0):

## Infinite Prisoner's Infilemma

### Introduction

In this [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, you are going to
write a program that will play the game of the
**Infinite Prisoner's Infilemma**.

This game is based on the classic game of the name
[Infinite Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Prisoners%27_Dilemma)
.

The original inspiration for this game came from [this
game](https://ncase.me/trust/) by
[Nicky Case](https://www.ncase.me/).

By default we will include the sample bots from Nicky
Case's game. You can also add your own bots.

### How to Play

Given a list of bot models `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

- First, multiply the list by 10 to get 10 bots of each model.
- Then, battle every two bots together.

During a battle there will be 10 rounds. Each round:

- Both players will enter `x` dollars into a machine, where
  `x` is non-negative (not neccessarily an integer) and less
  than or equal to the amount of money they have. They start
  with $100.
- The other player will recieve 1.1 times the amount of money.

### Default Bots

Default bots are:

- Copycat, which starts by cooperating with 1/3 of his money,
  and then cooperates with the same ammount of money as the
  ammount of money you cooperated last turn. (Unless he doesn't
  have enough money, which he will use all of them).
- AlwaysCheat, which, always cheats by giving no money. DUH!
- AlwaysCooperate, which, always cooperates by giving 1/2 of his
  money.
- Grudger, which starts by cooperating with 1/3 of his money but
  gives no more money if you have ever cheated and give less than
  $10.
- Detective, which cooperates $20, $5, $10, but if the opponent
  always gave at least $50, will act like an AlwaysCheat, else
  will act like a Copycat.
- Copykitten, which is similar to Copycat, but cooperates with
  the same ammount of money as the max of the opponent's last
  two turns.
- Simpleton, which starts by cooperating 1/2 of his money, then
  at every turn, if the opponent gave less than $20, switch a
  state between 1/2 of his money and none.
- Random, which give, randomly, 2/3 to none of his money.

### Instructions

Your bot should be a class. It will inherit from this Bot class:

```python
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 100
        self.information = {}

    def log(self, bot, money):
        if bot not in self.information:
            self.information[bot] = [money]
        else:
            self.information[bot] += [money]

    def change_money(self, money):
        self.money += money

    def choice(self, bot):
        pass # override in subclass

    def name(self):
        pass # should return the name of the bot

    def get_choice(self, bot):
        choice = self.choice(bot)
        assert 0 <= choice <= self.money, \
            f"Invalid choice {choice}, bot money {self.money}" # check if choice is valid
        return choice
```

You may **not** use any other libraries other than `math`
and `random`. (If you have any requests, let me know.
I mainly want to ban the use of `inspect`, `sys`, and `os`.)

You may also **not** override any methods other than `choice` and
`name`.

You may **not** set `self.money`.
(Else, you can come up with self.money = 10000, etc.)

The following is a sample bot:

```python
from main import Bot # <-- import the Bot class
from random import random as r # <-- import the random function

class TestBot(Bot): # <-- create a class called TestBot
                    # <-- that inherits from Bot
    def choice(self, bot): # <-- override the choice method
        return self.money*r()/10 # random number between 0 and
                                 # 10% of the bot's money
    def name(self): # <-- override the name method
        return "randombot" # <-- return the name of the bot

bot = TestBot # <-- IMPORTANT: create a variable called bot
```

### The Information Log

Well, sometimes you want to know what the opponent did.
Thus, sometimes you need the "information log", called
via `self.information`. Remember the `bot` argument
that is passed in the `choice` method? That is your
opponent. To get the information log of your opponent,
use the following:

```python
self.information[bot] # <-- get the information log of the opponent
```

What does that information look like? Well, it's like
`[[Y1,O1],[Y2,O2],...]`. `Y1` is what you gave the
opponent in round 1. The rest is fairly easy to infer.

### Controller Script

```python
# This is the controller script for the Infinite Prisoner's Infilemma King of the Hill game.

bots = ['testbot','randombot'] # Will change.

# to make it fold-able.
if True:

    from rich.console import Console
    from rich.table import Table
    console = Console()
    with open('log.txt','w') as f: pass

    def print(*args, **kwargs): console.print(*args, **kwargs)

    def log(*text):
        with open('log.txt','a') as f:
            f.write(' '.join(list(map(str,text)))+'\n')

    def play(Bot1, Bot2):
        log(Bot1.name(), 'vs', Bot2.name())
        b1_choice, b2_choice = Bot1.get_choice(Bot2), Bot2.get_choice(Bot1)
        Bot1.change_money(-b1_choice)
        Bot2.change_money(-b2_choice)
        log(b1_choice, b2_choice)
        Bot1.change_money(1.001*b2_choice)
        Bot2.change_money(1.001*b1_choice)
        log(Bot1.name(), 'has', Bot1.money, 'dollars')
        log(Bot2.name(), 'has', Bot2.money, 'dollars')
        Bot1.log(Bot2, b1_choice, b2_choice)
        Bot2.log(Bot1, b2_choice, b1_choice)
        log('\n\n')

    class Bot:
        def __init__(self):
            self.money = 100
            self.information = {}

        def log(self, bot, money):
            if bot not in self.information:
                self.information[bot] = [money]
            else:
                self.information[bot] += [money]

        def change_money(self, money):
            self.money += money

        def choice(self, bot):
            pass # override in subclass

        def name(self):
            pass # should return the name of the bot

        def get_choice(self, bot):
            choice = self.choice(bot)
            assert 0 <= choice <= self.money, \
                f"Invalid choice {choice}, bot money {self.money}" # check if choice is valid
            return choice

    def leaderboard(Bots):
        table = Table(show_header=True, header_style="bold #00ffff")
        table.add_column("Bot", style="bold #ffff00") # yellow
        table.add_column("Money", justify="right", style="#00ff00") # green
        for bot in sorted(Bots, key=lambda x:-x.money):
            table.add_row(bot.name()+'     ',
                          f"     ${str(round(bot.money,2)) if str(round(bot.money,2))[::-1][1] != '.' else str(round(bot.money,2))+'0'}")
        print(table)

    def main():
        print('\n\n\n')

        Bots = []
        for bot in bots:
            for i in range(10): Bots.append(__import__(bot).bot())

        for Bot1 in Bots:
            for Bot2 in Bots:
                if Bot1 is not Bot2:
                    for i in range(10): play(Bot1,Bot2)

        leaderboard(Bots)
        print('\n\n\n')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Compute the cophenetic correlation coefficient

Meta question at the end.

**Background**

The cophenetic correlation coefficient is used in bioinformatic to measure how close the distances of a tree are to the distances of the original distance matrix.

It is defined as follows:
\${\displaystyle c={\frac {\sum _{i < j}(D_{ij}-{\bar {D}})(T_{ij}-{\bar {T}})}{\sqrt {\sum _{i < j}(D_{ij}-{\bar {D}})^{2}\sum _{i<j}(T_{ij}-{\bar {T}})^{2}}}}}\$

More information:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cophenetic_correlation)
- [Mathworks](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/cophenet.html)
- [Farris, (1969). On the Cophenetic Correlation Coefficient. SysZoo. 18.](https://doi.org/10.2307/2412324)

**Input:**

- D: CSV style-string to first matrix
- T: CSV style-string to second matrix

The input have the following format:

Eg 1: `D.dist`

```
N31
B14A.0, 2.0
N20, 3.0, 4.1
N20S, 12.0, 23.9, 4.3
EES.0, 10.3, 19.0, 16.0, 17.0
S2.0, 201.1, 99.6, 233.0, 297.0, 281.00
```

Eg. 2: `T.dist`

```
N31
B14A.0, 1.7
N20, 3.9, 4.1
N20S, 32.0, 25.1, 4.3
EES.0, 12.3, 19.5, 16.1, 17.1
S2.0, 202.2, 105.6, 227.1, 281.1, 283.5
```

The first column is a for us uninteresting identifier, the values (floats) are separated by a `,`.

**Output:**

The cophenetic correlation coefficient.

**Example:**

Using the two matrices from above:  0.9982682565

### Meta

Is it okay to use a file path as input? Or should I reformulate this question to input two matrices directly?

Answer (score 0):

## Don't like the middles

There will be no winner on these question. Just for the fun of the challenge.

Your job will be to output every sequence of each 10 numbers, alternating between the evens and odds, but removing the middle number, which means all numbers terminating in 4 or 5 must not be generated.

Here it goes exemplified for the first elements:

```
0 2 6 8
1 3 7 9
10 12 16 18
11 13 17 19
...
```

It is not mandatory you need to pretty format or have a list of sub-lists as shown here. One list or a string where each element is clearly separated from the previous and the next ones is enough.

Comment: Objective scoring criteria don't make challenges less fun; they're what make a challenge a challenge. They're also mandatory :P

Answer (score 0):

## Perform division for fuzzy numbers

### Objective

Given two positive "fuzzy" numbers (as defined below), perform division between them.

### Definition

Here, a **fuzzy number** consists of two integers: \$n\$ and \$r\$. It indicates that the number is from a measurement, and thus may carry an error. The measured number is \$n×2^r\$, and the maximum error is \$2^{r-1}\$.

In other words, the pair \$(n,r)\$ indicates that the exact number can be any of those from \$n×2^r - 2^{r-1}\$ and \$n×2^r + 2^{r-1}\$. As per the rounding convention, the boundaries are inclusive if \$n\$ is even, and exclusive if \$n\$ is odd.

In this challenge, only positive fuzzy numbers shall be considered. In other words, \$n\$ shall be positive.

### Operation

Here, the operation in concern is division. Performing \$(n_1,r_1) ÷ (n_2,r_2)\$, the exact result of division is within the range from \$(n_1×2^{r_1} - 2^{r_1-1})/(n_2×2^{r_2} + 2^{r_2-1})\$ to \$(n_1×2^{r_1} + 2^{r_1-1})/(n_2×2^{r_2} - 2^{r_2-1})\$, where boundaries are inclusive if and only if both \$n_1\$ and \$n_2\$ are even.

The range indicated by result \$(n,r)\$ shall cover the range above as **precisely** as possible. That is, \$r\$ must be as small as possible. As a tiebreaker, the range must be as **accurate** as possible. That is, \$n\$ must be chosen so that \$n×2^r\$ would be as near as possible to:
$$
½((n_1×2^{r_1} - 2^{r_1-1})/(n_2×2^{r_2} + 2^{r_2-1}) + (n_1×2^{r_1} + 2^{r_1-1})/(n_2×2^{r_2} - 2^{r_2-1})) \\ =(4n_1n_2+1)/(4n_2^2-1)×2^{r_1-r_2}
$$

For ranges with equal radii, those excluding boundaries shall be considered preciser than those including boundaries. This ensures uniqueness of the result.

### Ungolfed solution

(WIP)

Comment: I think apart from unglofed solution (WIP, but I'm not a fan of posting reference implementations in a question) and some test-cases, there should be at least one or two thoroughly worked out examples. Also, please remember about specifying [an objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria) and I/O requirements (if any).

Answer (score 0):

## I X the source code, you Y the output!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

---

There's a zillion challenges of the form "I [do a thing to] the source code, you [do a thing to] the output!", like [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558/i-double-the-source-you-double-the-output) and [I reverse the source code, you negate the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output). In this challenge you'll generalize that, writing a program that, given two functions `x` and `y`, will print a program `p` which prints some output `o`, with the property that `x(p)` prints `y(o)`.

**Task:**

Your program (or function) should take two inputs, `x` and `y`, which can either be functions/lambdas, strings containing code, or some similar representation of a function in your language. You can assume these functions are pure: they have no side effects and do not depend on anything aside from their input. Other reasonable assumptions may be made based on your language's requirements, such as the input to `x` being a string of a certain length.

Your program should then print or return a program `p`, once again either as a **pure** lambda function (so it can't rely on `x` and `y` in the scope above it), a string representation of a program, function, or snippet, or some similar representation, such as writing an executable to a file. When `p` is run, it should take no input, and produce a deterministic value `o`. When `x(p)` is run, a second program will be produced, which, when run without input, should produce `y(o)` deterministically.

You may assume the data type of `y(o)` is the same as `o`, and make any other reasonable assumptions for your language. You may use any consistent data type for `o`, as long as it can hold more than 128 or so values (ints, floats, or strings would be preferred).

**Sandbox:**

This would be a very difficult challenge, and I'm not entirely sure what it would involve to answer or if it would even be possible to do so. I'm going to have to make some additional rules I think. maybe the inverse of `x` would be another input, that sort of thing. Feel free to suggest any ideas for rules to make this more possible and/or interesting, including across languages.

Comment: what if `x` is, say, `return ""`? or something else disruptive like `z=>return "exitprogram()"+z`

Comment: If `x` is an arbitrary function, this is impossible. Consider `x` being the identity function: `p` and `x(p)` are the same, so their outputs must be the same (since they must be pure and deterministic). For almost all `y` (in fact, all `y` except the identity function), this becomes impossible. You'd have to put some kind of very strong restriction on `x` for this to be doable, which I don't think can make it an interesting challenge. Either that, or allow solutions to be uncomputable (...cont'd)

Comment: (...cont'd) (A "valid" but uncomputable solution could be of the form: generate every program `p` and compute `x(p)`, and check that `y(eval(p)) == eval(x(p))`). Some more (less trivial) logic can be used to show that this is also impossible if `y` is an arbitrary function.

Comment: @pxeger Yes, it's not possible with a number of `x`s and `y`s. I don't think restricting it so that it's possible makes it less interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

## Interleavable programs (WIP) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

Your task in this challenge is to create programs that can be interleaved. Submissions will be in the form of collections of programs. The score for each collection is 2 raised to the power of the number of programs in that collection, and your total score is the sums of the scores of all the submitted collections. Here are the rules for each collection:

- There must be at least 2 programs in each collection
- The programs in the collection must be ordered from 1 to \$n\$
- The \$n\$th program must output the integers in the range \$(i-1)*n\$ to \$i*n\$. Output can be as a list or string with separators (the separator can be an empty string)
- When your programs are interleaved, their output is also interleaved
- Programs can be reused in other collections

### Example answer, score = 12

Collection 1:

1. `abcdef`
2. `123`
3. `jklom`

Interleaved: `a1jb2kc3ldoemf`

Collection 2:

1. `abcdef`
2. `123`

Interleaved: `a1b2c3def`

### Questions for Meta

- How do I make the description clearer? It's not great right now.
- Is this a dupe?
- Should the output be modified so it's easier? Maybe people can choose their own output?
- Any way to improve the scoring? How do I prevent people gaming the score by posting answers with lots of collections of size 2? I was thinking about forcing all programs in all collections to be drawn from the biggest collection.
- Is this even worth posting as a question?

Answer (score 0):

## [Transform characters of your choice into "Hello, world!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250556/101306) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: "takes character as input and outputs character", does it mean that the program output a _single_ character? "fed into the program one by one", does it mean that the program take all 13 characters as input? If the program cannot store data between runs, how could it yield different output for same input?

Comment: @tsh you get to choose which 13 characters are input. so you could, for example, have it so that inputting each of "abcdefghijklm" outputs a character of "Hello, world!". Every other character input would just have to output a character, with no further restriction.

Comment: I suspect in most languages it would be optimal to write a program which outputs its input, and use "Hello, world!" as the input, which isn't particularly interesting

Comment: @CommandMaster This is why I chose that it have to be unique characters, so cat program can't be used anymore. (character `o` is there two times, character `l` three times)

Answer (score 0):

## Input program generating Fibonacci, output program generating Fibonacci [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci) [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

**Challenge:**

You will have to write program, which outputs program, that outputs single [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). First program should output first element of sequence (`0`), second should output second element of sequence (`1`), etc. You can also write two input strings - first is input to your program when it is first launched. Second will be always input to the generated program. The next time your program is launched, it's input will be the program it generated previously.

**Rules:**

- Your score is sum of length of program and input strings.
- Your inputs can be something else than string (numbers, booleans). To get your score, treat them like strings. E.g. `true` have length 4, `123,false` have length 9.
- You can use two different languages for the programs, but solutions using single language are preferred.

[**Output sequence (A000045):**](http://oeis.org/A000045)

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, ...
```

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31529/fibonacci-program-lengths)

Comment: "write two input strings", maybe "take two input strings"?

Comment: "that outputs single Fibonacci number" do I required to output `0` for first outputted program, and `1` for the second one, ...? Or maybe I can always output `0` since it is a "Fibonacci number"?

Comment: @tsh I made edit to address your second comment. Also I think that "write" as well as "take" is correct. But I wanted to say that this challenge is not just about writing program which you submit to your answer, but you can also write the input which counts towards byte count and is also part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Make an ASCII art arrow [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Given a size and direction (up, down, left, or right), you will create an ASCII art arrow.

### Drawing it

#### For an arrow pointing up

For size \$s\$, there are \$2s\$ `|` characters in the center, with 1 `_` character at the top. On the left of each of the top \$s\$ pipe characters, there is a `/` diagonally aligned with the arrow, and on the right side, the same but with backslashes.

```
Size 1:
 _
/|\
 |


Size 2:
  _
 /|\
/ | \
  |
  |
```

#### An arrow pointing down

Similar to an arrow facing up, it will have \$2s\$ (where \$s\$ is still the size) vertical `|` characters, with a hyphen below them.  Starting from the bottom `|`, diagonally distribute slashes and backslashes on each side (only going up \$s\$ `|` characters).

```
Size 1:

 |
\|/
 -


Size 2:

  |
  |
\ | /
 \|/
  -
```

#### An arrow pointing left

Where \$s\$ is the size, there should be \$2s\$ hyphens going horizontally, with 1 `|` on the left of them. Starting from the leftmost hyphen, going up to the \$s\$th hyphen, diagonally distribute `/` and `\` spreading out.

```
Size 1:

 /
|--
 \

Size 2:

  /
 /
|----
 \
  \
```

#### An arrow pointing right

This is pretty much an arrow pointing left, but inverted.

Where \$s\$ is the size, there should be \$2s\$ hyphens going horizontally, with 1 `|` on the right of them. Starting from the rightmost hyphen, going to the \$s\$th last hyphen, diagonally distribute `/` and `\` spreading out.

```
Size 1:

 \
--|
 /

Size 2:

  \
   \
----|
   /
  /
```

### Rules

- As for the size, you may take any of \$n-1\$, \$n\$, \$n+1\$, or \$2n\$.
- For the direction, you may use any four consistent values.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code for each language wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Standard I/O rules apply.

## Meta

- Is this clear?
- Is this too boring, or too similar to another challenge?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186548/ascii-meme-arrow-generator).

Comment: Suggestion: make the arrows "pointy" (with `^v<>`) - this may however make the challenge harder as would prevent simple reflection of up/down and right/left pairs.

Comment: @pajonk I didn't do that because it looked fine on the up/down ones, but with left/right, it just looked really weird.

Answer (score 0):

## Get string from CIGAR and reference

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[alignment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment)

In the field of genomics, **CIGAR** (Concise Idiosyncratic Gapped Alignment Report) **strings** are sometimes used to indicate how a DNA sequence aligns to a reference sequence of DNA. CIGAR strings are sequences of `<operation, length>` pairs. An operation can be `M`, meaning "match", `I`, meaning "insert", or `D`, meaning delete. The length describes the number of times the operation is repeated<sup>1</sup>. (For our purposes, we'll assume a match means that both matched characters are the same -- i.e. an alignment match.)

Suppose we align string \$S\$ to reference string \$R\$, producing CIGAR string \$C\$. You can think of the CIGAR string \$C\$ as operations applied to \$R\$ to turn it into \$S\$. If we treat \$R\$ as a sequence of consumable tokens, then to get \$R\$:

- Iterate through the pairs `<operation, length>` in \$C\$:

  - `length` times, repeat `operation`:

    - If `operation` is `I`, output a character different than the current token of \$R\$
    - If `operation` is `D`, consume the current token of \$R\$
    - If `operation` is `M`, consume and output the current token of \$R\$

(Note: You can assume that for any input CIGAR string, all tokens in \$R\$ will be consumed. In other words, the length of \$R\$ equals the number of `M` and `D` operations applied.)

For example, suppose we've aligned the DNA string `ACAACTA` to the reference `ACTCAGTA` as follows:

```
AC-AAC--TAC 
ACT--CAGTAC
MMDIIMDDMMM
```

This would be encoded as `M2D1I2M1D2M3`.

Another example:

```
-G-T--G-AT--GGCG-T
AGCTGCGCATAA-GC-A-
DMDMDDMDMMDDIDDIDI
```

Which is encoded as `D1M1D1M1D2M1D1M2D2I1D2I1D1I1`.

**The challenge:** Given the reference string \$R\$ and a CIGAR string \$C\$, output a string \$S\$ which would produce the CIGAR string \$C\$ when aligned to \$R\$. (There are obviously many cases where there are many possible strings which satisfy this condition -- you can output any one of them.)

Test cases:

| \$R\$ | \$C\$ | \$S\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AAA` | `M3` | `AAA` |
| `AAA` | `I3D3` | `CCC` |
| `AAA` | `D3I3` | `CCC` |
| `AAA` | `D1I1D1I2D1` | `CCC` |
| `AAA` | `D3` | (the empty string) |
| `AAA` | `M1D2I1` | `AC` |
| `ACTCAGTA` | `M2D1I2M1D2M3` | `ACAACTA` |
| `AGCTGCGCATAAGCA` | `D1M1D1M1D2M1D1M2D2I1D2I1D1I1` | `GTGATGGCGT` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Because this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

<sup>1</sup>Paraphrased from https://www.ebi.ac.uk/about/vertebrate-genomics/software/exonerate-manual

## Questions

The more obvious question would be "given reference \$R\$ and aligning string \$S\$, find the cigar string corresponding to the best possible alignment", but that probably has been done already, and I've already accidentally posted a duplicate question...

I almost certainly should explain alignment better, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

## Generate number set with conditions using n numbers

Comment: Is this the same as "generate \$T=\{T_1, ..., T_x\}\$, the minimum number of \$k\$-length subsets of \$\{1,...,n\}\$ such that every \$v\$-length subset of \$\{1,...,n\}\$ is a subset of some set in \$T\$"?

Comment: @Adam yes It is same ? Has this been asked already? Or do you want me to change description to this ?

Comment: For future reference a quote from the main sandbox post above: "It is recommended to leave your posts in the sandbox for at least several days, and until it receives upvotes and any feedback has been addressed." Some of the issues raised in the main site could have been caught and addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

### [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential)

## `Hello, World!` hashing

Implement a one-way hashing function that generates arbitrary strings which have a chance (obviously input dependent) of producing at least any of the printable ASCII characters when provided an input of at least 2 characters. This can be any mechanism you choose and could always output a fixed length if desired, however when your source code is used as input, the resultant output must be `Hello, World!`.

### Rules

- The input string will always be 2 characters or more (meaning your code must be at least two characters).
- There are no other special requirements for any other input strings.
- The output should not be exactly the same as the input (this might be unavoidable in some scenarios with well-crafted input, but you can't just output your input if the code `Hello, World!`, by some magic, in your language performs some sort of hashing).
- It should be feasible to get at least any of the printable ASCII characters as output. You are however not limited to printable ASCII output and may output any combination of bytes (e.g. unprintables, UTF-8 sequences)
- All characters of the input string should be taken into account when generating strings, not just the first 13 and should affect the output.

---

## For meta

I'd really like to encourage answers that aren't a condition that just compares input with source and outputs `Hello, World!` in that instance, but as [pointed out by @pajonk](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25007?noredirect=1#comment78072_25007) it's a non-observable requirement.

Comment: I think you can use tags [tag:code-golf], [tag:hello-world] and [tag:restricted-source]. Can you also explain what does "strings consisting of at least (but not limited to) the printable ASCII" mean? (That some strings have to contain printable characters or all strings have to contain printable characters?) Also does full input string have to be used to calculate hash? I expect some people might want to use just fixed part of input string to make this task easier.

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:self-referential]. Be careful with [non-observable requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/55372) (like `you must not have a special condition`), as they are discouraged. Also, you may define what does `most inputs should result in different output` mean exactly (or drop it), as this may be considered too vague.

Comment: @Jiří My intention with that wording is that the output you generate must at least have the possibility for any character in the printable ASCII range to be included, but may also output unprintables or higher byte value unicode chars for instance. The full input string must also be used, yes. So changing a character at the end of the string should change the value returned. I'll clarify that. Also, not entirely sure on restricted-source, but I'll check the wiki, thank you!

Comment: @pajonk Yeah, that's a good point. I guess I didn't want an arbitrary hashing algorithm with a `if input == source` condition (which I think would be considerably easier). Good point about the wording on `most inputs` I'll clarify along with Jiří's suggestion of ensuring all characters are used and can affect the output, hopefully that covers that off. I'll look at self-referential too. Thank you!

Comment: @pajonk I can't think of a way to make an observable requirement to avoid the simpler solution which makes me inclined to remove this as I think it trivialises the problem. Any idea on how to enforce that without having this blacklisted?

Comment: @DomHastings remember that simple comparison `input==source` is not so simple, as requires a modified version of a quine. This may or may not be shorter than other possible approaches.

Comment: Also I was thinking how I would write answer for this and came up with following idea: Sum all characters on input and then add this sum to ASCII codes of individual characters of string "Hello, World!" (%256). Would this answer be fine?

Comment: @Jiří yeah, absolutely!

Comment: @pajonk I guess so, I feel like modified quines aren't that interesting sometimes... But you're right, probably not trivial in every language. I guess the kinda of answer is love to see is a generic mechanism that is calculated to, based on the code as input, the exact string required, but that might be a big request! It's an interesting problem (to me at least) as it felt easier than I've found it upon trying to execute it!

Answer (score 0):

### For Meta

This challenge is currently just a very undeveloped idea I had today! So I'm just dumping it here to start getting feedback and somewhere to leave my own thoughts and notes as I start this.

As this is in such a undeveloped form and I'm not sure when I'll have time to do it, other people are very much encouraged to develop this if they want!

I'm hoping to end up with something with a similar format to @trichoplax's [Formic Functions - Ant Queen of the Hill Contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135102/63404).

##### Notes

- even a simple chess engine may be so complex that even expert golfing may have no effect on catching a better written engine in size
- scoring seems very messy if you include game_length and function_length as these numbers could be all sorts of sizes
- would checkers be a better/simpler game to do this with?
- making it single language (javascript) would make it very easy to implement for me but would make golfing less interesting?

---

## The Code Golf Chess Invitational

I have developed a simple chess interface (to be written) that will:

1. provide board state to your function
2. wait for your functions move
3. verify your move

   - invalid moves will result in a loss
4. make the move
5. repeat for the opponent
6. and repeat until there is a winner
7. then score both functions

#### The score

The score of each function will be determined by the length of each function and the number of moves the game lasted. With higher scores being worse!

- Winners score will be `1 * length_of_program`
- Losers score will be `game_length * length_of_program`
- Losing by invalid move score will be `(game_length)^2 * length_of_program`

(Scoring very much to be revised but ideally I want to encourage short programs, encourage winning, and absolutely discourage invalid moves (random playing))

### Your function

- MUST NOT query other sites/libraries/etc

  - it could include an entire library if you wished, but that would obviously be a very long function
- should take a 2d array as input of the board state, [[a1, a2 ... a8], [b1 ... h8]]
- return a chess move in [chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess))
- warnings (and errors?) are fine as long as the program still returns a move
- normal other restrictions apply

### You, yourself

- Please provide assistance in getting your function running on the GitHub site!

(this needs work because whilst I'm sure I could get many common languages (esp scripting languages) working I'm not sure how well I'd do with some of the more golf-y/compiled languages)

### Tournament

The initial tournament would be a continuous round robin of all current submissions with each functions running score an average of each score each game.

Then a final day, where every function competes against every function x times. This would decide the "winner" of the competition and the accepted answer tick.

Then just for fun a seeded knockout tournament (based on the final score) to decide who had the best chess program. (Maybe a bounty award for this)

Comment: I think you should make winners score `0` and losers (including invalid moves) `length_of_program+10` or something similar. Because currently the best strategy is to lose game at beginning by invalid move. Anyway, if you decide my idea of scoring isn't good enough, then it feels weird to punish losers for long games - I expect that longer games are harder and shorter games are simpler, so the scoring should be opposite.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement Bloom filter insertion

A **Bloom filter** is a probabilistic data structure that is used to determine whether an element is in a set in a fixed number of bits. It consists of:

1. a bit array \$B\$ of fixed size \$m\$, initialized as all \$0\$s, and
2. \$k\$ different hash functions \$h_1,\ldots,h_k\$ which each map any element to some value \$v \in 0,\ldots,m-1\$.

To insert element \$s\$ into the set, set \$B[h_i(s)]\$ to \$1\$ for each hash function \$h_i\$.

To check if element \$s\$ is in the set, check the value of \$B[h_i(s)]\$ for each hash function \$h_i\$. If they are all \$1\$, return true; otherwise return false.

For example, suppose we start with bit array of size 5:

```
0 0 0 0 0
```

We also define hash functions \$h_1(s) = s\bmod m, h_2(s) = (s^2)\bmod m\$. To insert value \$13\$, We calculate the indices to change:
$$i_1 = h_1(13) = 13\bmod 5 = 3,\\
i_2 = h_2(13) = (13^2)\bmod 5 = 4$$
So we set \$B[3]\$ and \$B[4]\$ to \$1\$:

```
0 0 0 1 1
```

To check if \$13\$ is in the set, we look if \$B[3]\$ and \$B[4]\$ are both \$1\$.

### The challenge

You should implement the *insertion* part of a Bloom filter.
Take in three inputs: two positive integers \$m\$ and \$k\$, and a series of non-negative integers \$S=\{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}\$. Output the bit array of the Bloom filter of size \$m\$ with all the elements of \$S\$ added using \$k\$ hash functions, with any two distinct values substituting for \$1\$ and \$0\$.

You can choose any \$k\$ hash functions as long as they have *uniformly distributed output* and are *not perfectly correlated* (probably the wrong term for this). In other words:

- Over all non-negative integers \$\{s\}\$, the probability of \$h_i(s)=v\in\{0,\ldots,m-1\}\$ is \$\frac1m\$.
- For all pairs of functions \$(h_i,h_j)\$, there is not a mapping between the output of \$h_i\$ and the output of \$h_j\$. For example, you couldn't use \$h_1(s) = s\bmod m, h_2(s) = (s+1)\bmod m,\$ because you can perfectly determine the output of \$h_2\$ from the output of \$h_1\$.

(Ideally, these functions should be independent, but that's not a practical request.)

### Examples

TODO

## Questions

I could ask for both insertion and value checking, but I don't want to overcomplicate this.

Answer (score 0):

## All permutations of range from \$1\$ to \$n\$

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Given a positive input \$n\$, output all permutations of either \$\{0,1,\ldots,n\}\$ or \$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\$.

### Examples

Outputting permutations of \$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\$.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `[(1)]` |
| `2` | `[(1, 2), (2, 1)]` |
| `4` | `[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. The shortest code wins.

### Questions

I was looking for this challenge, but I couldn't find it posted anywhere. Maybe because it's too derivative of a simple "output all permutations" challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## [Generate a Kirkman triple system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251041/110698)

Answer (score 0):

## [smallest number of steps for a knight in chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251050/smallest-number-of-steps-for-a-knight-in-chess)

Comment: I've edited this down to a stub now that it's been posted to save space

Answer (score 0):

### Program a compiler compiler

Write a program, function, or likewise that takes in a [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)-like grammar specification(see below) and outputs a program or function in a language of your choice that takes strings as input and returns truthy if that string is parseable with the specified grammar, and false otherwise.

### Meta-language:

The input to your program will consist of a number of bnf-like rules. Each definition will be on its own line, and will consist of a name (string of 1 or more characters `[a-z0-9]`), followed by the symbol `::=` followed by a string of symbols(terminal and non terminal), terminals consist of `[a-zA-Z0-9() ]`. Nonterminals are denoted with a `<` followed by a string of characters `[a-z0-9]` followed by `>`; that string of characters refers to another definition. Each definition may have multiple alternatives, separated by `|`. Alternatives should be matched left to right. The first line of the input will share this same form, except that it will not have the name of the definition or the `::=`. This is the "top-level" definition that the input to the outputted program will attempt to be matched against.

Input grammars will never contain left-recursion (ie. it will never be the case that there will be a rule of the form `a::=<a>`). You may additionally assume that your generated program will only be given as input strings that contain only those characters comprising valid terminal symbol(`[a-zA-Z0-9() ]`). Additionally, your compiler-compiling program only needs to handle valid definitions.

### Examples:

The following should be handled appropriately by your program:

```
binaryliteral
binaryliteral::=0<binaryliteral>|1<binaryliteral>|0|1
```

This means that the generated program should return truthy for any strings that match the definition of a binary literal, which is either the character 0 or 1 followed by a binary literal, or just 0 or 1. This would recognize strings

```
quantexpr
quantexpr::=forall <var>(<expr1>)|exists <var>(<expr1>)
expr1::=<expr0> and <expr1>|<expr0> or <expr0> |not <expr1>|<expr0>
expr0::=<var>|(<expr1>)
var::=x|y|z
```

and you do not need to handle the following:

```
x:=1
```

```
expr
expr::=x|<expr> plus <expr>
```

As usual, this is code-golf, so the shortest program per (implementation, output language) pair wins!

Comment: This could use a bit of cleanup but I'm totally behind this idea, so +1. Note: i think your terminal string regex is wrong, `+-*` expresses a range. in general i think it'd be worth considering simplifying what terminals are allowed, but thats just my onpinioin

Comment: @thejonymyster good catch on that regex; I'll fix that. Is there anything else that needs to be changed pursuant to "cleaning up"?

Comment: sorry for the nondescriptive wording on my part; I just think the meta language description could be broken down into smaller sections, maybe with a small worked-out example or two. As is, it's fairly clear but just a bit densely packed. Additionally, I think you should link to something (maybe wikipedia) about BNF, for those entirely unfamiliar. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Add numbers as fairly as possible

Given an array of integers \$X\$ and an array of positive integers \$A\$, figure out how to add the values in \$A\$ to the values in \$X\$ such that the *variance* of the updated values is as small as possible. (You can add more than one value from \$A\$ to a given value in \$X\$.)

[Explanation of variance]

If there are multiple solutions, you can output any of them. Output in any reasonable format.

#### Example

Suppose \$X = [4,5,6]\$ and \$A=[1,2]\$. The "most fair" way to distribute the value \$1\$ to \$4\$ and \$2\$ to \$5\$, making the updated array \$X' = [6,6,6]\$, which has a variance of \$0\$.
Therefore, you should output something like `[[2],[1],[]]` or `{4:[2],5:[1]}`.

### Test Cases

[TODO]

## Questions

I am almost certain a question like this has been done before, which is why I'm not putting much effort into this post.

Answer (score 0):

## Contrasting Colors [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

When designing a website or poster or book it's important to make the graphical elements be distinct. A common mistake is to choose colors to similar to eachother. We must prevent this!

The goal of this challenge is simple: Given a initial color and a number of colors to generate, generate N colors that each have maximal contrast to each of the previous colors.

Contrast is defined as the sum of absolute differences. The contrast of a new color is the minimum of the distances to all previous colors. You do *not* need to consider gamma. Colors are a 3 tuple with each value a integer ranging from 0 to 255.

You must use a greedy algorithm. AKA you shouldn't consider the number or even existence of colors afterwards, just colors before. This is because in the design each subsequent color will be used significantly less.

In some cases, multiple choices are available. In this case you may pick any. Thus your results might not look the same as my test cases but still be valid.

You may chose whether to include the initial value in the output or not.

This is code golf, shortest answer wins.

### Test cases

```json
{
    [(255,255,255),5]: [(255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), (0, 127, 255), (63, 255, 64), (191, 0, 191), (254, 128, 0)],
    [(255,0,128),5]: [(255, 0, 128), (0, 255, 0), (0, 64, 255), (191, 255, 223), (32, 0, 32), (192, 128, 0)],
    [(128,128,128),10]: [(128, 128, 128), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (32, 32, 223), (32, 223, 32), (223, 32, 32), (223, 223, 224), (0, 81, 111), (81, 96, 15)],
    [(7,91,7), 5]: [(7, 91, 7), (255, 255, 255), (89, 0, 255), (255, 0, 44), (0, 211, 217), (173, 255, 0)]
}
```

Comment: Do we need to include the initial color in the output? The text suggests no, but the test-cases do include it. Also, are the color values required to be integer?

Comment: You may or may not include the initial value, your choice. Colors must be integers. I'll clarify

Answer (score 0):

**The least amount a steps a chess pice can reach a position**

I have previously posted a challange: [smallest number of steps for a knight in chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251050/113952).
Now I would like to go a step further by adding the possibility to choose you piece.

If you place a pice on any square of a chessboard, what is the smallest amount of steps to reach every possible position?

**Rules**

- It is an 8 by 8 board.
- The given input is a coordinate (x,x) and the chosen piece. Explain in the answer how to input the piece of choice.
- The piece starts at an arbitrary position, taken as input.
- The pawn can not start at the bottom row, and can not move 2 steps (like when in the startposition).
- point '.' will be placed if a pice cannot reach the square.

**Example** 
With input `1, 0` for a knight, we start by putting a 0 in that position:

```
. 0
```

From her on we continue to fill the entire 8x8 board.
For a knight the output will look like follow

```
3 0 3 2 3 2 3 4
2 3 2 1 2 3 4 3
1 2 1 4 3 2 3 4
2 3 2 3 2 3 4 3
3 2 3 2 3 4 3 4
4 3 4 3 4 3 4 5
3 4 3 4 3 4 5 4
4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5
```

For a pawn with input (1, 7) the output will look like follow

```
. 6 . . . . . . 
. 5 . . . . . . 
. 4 . . . . . . 
. 3 . . . . . . 
. 2 . . . . . . 
. 1 . . . . . . 
. 0 . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

In the examples, I start counting from zero but it does not matter if you start from  or one.

**Challenge**
The pattern printed for a pice, as short as possible, in any reasonable format.

Comment: I'd recommend allowing the piece indicator to be any 6 distinct values, rather than requiring them to be 0,1,...,5 in a certain order.

Comment: Also, a few typos: "stap" (step), "you pice" (your piece), "pice" (piece), "nummerate" (enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

## Strategy: The cunning cousin witch

The [wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251029/optimal-strategy-to-defeat-the-wizard) has a cunning cousin who is a witch. She looks down on the wizard, regarding him and his puzzles as mathematically naive.  On reading his latest puzzle, she scorned him for always asking discrete problems with what she (unfairly) characterises as simple solutions, where the real, proper question should be continuous. To prove her point she poses the following version of the wizard's puzzle. (He reluctantly permits the partial plagiarism.)

Consider the following setup. An evil witch has a number line stretching from 0 to 10 which is hidden from you.  Also hidden from you she chooses a random integer \$x \in \{0, \dots, 10\}\$ and places that many points onto the number line uniformly at random. To be more precise, she places each of the \$x\$ points independently and uniformly at random onto the number line.  Your task is to prove that \$x = 10\$ and if you do the witch will grant you what she promises is a much better wish than what her cousin can provide.

In this game, you can at each step choose a floating point number \$y\$ and the witch will tell you the number of points on the number line with value less than or equal to \$y\$.

However the witch, being at least as evil as her cousin, will not let you choose a number larger than \$9\$. This might still be OK as you might still find 10 points and in fact the only way to be granted the wish is to have found all 10 points with values 9 or less.

The cost for choosing a floating point number \$\ell\$ is \$2^{\ell}\$ dollars.   At any point, you can choose to give up on this set of points and get her to start the whole process again (with a new random \$x\$). Of course, if you choose the number 9 and you still have not found 10 points you have no choice but to give up and start again. But you might want to give up earlier too. Sadly you never get any money back so your costs just carry on building.

Your goal is to devise a strategy that will get you the wish at the minimum expected cost. You should report your mean cost.

## Testing

Once you have chosen your strategy, you should run it until you get the wish 10,000 times and report the mean cost. If two answers have the same strategy, the one posted first wins. If two strategies have similar mean costs you may need to test it 100,000 or even more times to tell the difference.  Of course if you can directly compute the expected cost, all the better.

## Input and output

There is no input in this challenge. The output is just the mean cost to get a wish. To test your code you will need to implement both the witch and your strategy.

## What's a naive score?

If you just choose 9 each time then it will take you \$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{11} \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{10}} \approx 31.5\$  tries to find 10 points. This will cost you approximately \$16152.4\$ dollars.  How much better can you do?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I think it's more elegant if the values instead range from 0 to 1 -- the situation is exactly the same except that the values are scaled down.

Comment: @Adam I thought about that. The problem is that \$2^9=512\$ is a nicer number than \$2^{0.9} \approx 1.87\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [Persistence of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251656/persistence-of-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

## Set of all sets [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [set-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

Write a program or function which outputs all sets with a finite number of elements - but including sets that contain themselves (directly or indirectly).

These recursive sets will be represented using a system similar to [De Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index): an element of a set which is a reference to an outer enclosing set will be represented by a positive integer indicating how far "outside" that set is. For example, the set that contains itself, \$ s = \{s\} = \{\{\{\dots\}\}\} \$, is represented by `{1}`.

Note that some of these representations are equivalent (represent the same actual set). For example, `{{2}}` directly represents \$ s = \{\{s\}\} = \{\{\{\dots\}\}\} \$, but this is equal to \$ s = \{s\} \$, and so `{1}` and `{{2}}` (and `{{{3}}}` etc.) are all equivalent.

Here are a few more examples of this representation:

- \$ s = \{\{\}, s\} = \{\{\},\{\{\},\{\{\},\dots\}\}\}\$ = `{{}, 1}` (or `{{}, {{}, 2}}` etc.)
- \$ s = \{\{\{\}\}, \{s\}\} = \{\{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\{\}\}, \{\dots\}\}\}\} \$ = `{{{}}, {2}}` (or `{{{}}, {{{{}}, {4}}}}` etc.)

### Rules

Your sequence of sets may be in any order, as this is an [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function) question. However, your sequence may never contain the same set more than once. (This includes the same set represented in different ways, e.g. `{1}` and `{{2}}`.)

- As with standard [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, you may choose to either:

  - Take an input `n` and output the `n`th term of the sequence
  - Take an input `n`and output the first `n` terms
  - Output the sequence indefinitely, e.g. using a generator
- You may use 0- or 1-indexing
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the aim is to minimise your program's length in bytes

---

## Meta

- I really don't think I've done a good job of explaining this challenge; please feel free to edit it to be clearer
- Does this representation have an existing name?
- Other potentially interesting challenges involving this representation could be: (Which of these would make for good challenges?)

  - Is this representation fully simplified? (e.g. yes for `{1}`, no for `{{2}}`)
  - Simplify this representation (e.g. `{{2}}` -> `{1}`)
  - Do these two representations represent the same set? (e.g. `{1}` = `{{2}}`; `{{}}` ≠ `{1}`)

Comment: You haven't defined when two sets are equal.  Are `{{1}}` and `{1}` equal?  How about `{1}` and `{1,{2}}`?  You probably should pick a consistent set theory that denies the axiom of regularity and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

(Inspired by https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25136/91213)

## Quarter Precision Floating Point Numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

We all love our floating point formats, floats and doubles. People who work in embedded may have used a even shorter format: The half precision floating point. However, what if you want a even smaller format? I present the **quarter precision floating point number**.

It is defined like this:

- 1 bit: `s` The sign. 1 is negative, 0 is positive.
- 3 bits: `e` The exponent -4. So `000` is `2**-4`, 100 is  `2**0` and `111` is `2**3`
- 4 bits: `f` The fraction f. A leading 1 bit is assumed.

Overall formula is `(2-s*2)*2**(e-4)*f|16`.

There is no 0, infinity, -infinity, NaN, or any subnormals.

### Task

Your task is to produce a pair of programs, one to convert from quarters to floats and one to convert from floats to quarters. Your score is the sum of the length of both programs. Input will always be exactly representable.

### Test Cases

These is a complete set of possible input values.

```
Quarters as:    Float Equivalent
bin      dec    
00000000 000    0.0625
00000001 001    0.06640625
00000010 002    0.0703125
00000011 003    0.07421875
00000100 004    0.078125
00000101 005    0.08203125
00000110 006    0.0859375
00000111 007    0.08984375
00001000 008    0.09375
00001001 009    0.09765625
00001010 010    0.1015625
00001011 011    0.10546875
00001100 012    0.109375
00001101 013    0.11328125
00001110 014    0.1171875
00001111 015    0.12109375
00010000 016    0.125
00010001 017    0.1328125
00010010 018    0.140625
00010011 019    0.1484375
00010100 020    0.15625
00010101 021    0.1640625
00010110 022    0.171875
00010111 023    0.1796875
00011000 024    0.1875
00011001 025    0.1953125
00011010 026    0.203125
00011011 027    0.2109375
00011100 028    0.21875
00011101 029    0.2265625
00011110 030    0.234375
00011111 031    0.2421875
00100000 032    0.25
00100001 033    0.265625
00100010 034    0.28125
00100011 035    0.296875
00100100 036    0.3125
00100101 037    0.328125
00100110 038    0.34375
00100111 039    0.359375
00101000 040    0.375
00101001 041    0.390625
00101010 042    0.40625
00101011 043    0.421875
00101100 044    0.4375
00101101 045    0.453125
00101110 046    0.46875
00101111 047    0.484375
00110000 048    0.5
00110001 049    0.53125
00110010 050    0.5625
00110011 051    0.59375
00110100 052    0.625
00110101 053    0.65625
00110110 054    0.6875
00110111 055    0.71875
00111000 056    0.75
00111001 057    0.78125
00111010 058    0.8125
00111011 059    0.84375
00111100 060    0.875
00111101 061    0.90625
00111110 062    0.9375
00111111 063    0.96875
01000000 064    1.0
01000001 065    1.0625
01000010 066    1.125
01000011 067    1.1875
01000100 068    1.25
01000101 069    1.3125
01000110 070    1.375
01000111 071    1.4375
01001000 072    1.5
01001001 073    1.5625
01001010 074    1.625
01001011 075    1.6875
01001100 076    1.75
01001101 077    1.8125
01001110 078    1.875
01001111 079    1.9375
01010000 080    2.0
01010001 081    2.125
01010010 082    2.25
01010011 083    2.375
01010100 084    2.5
01010101 085    2.625
01010110 086    2.75
01010111 087    2.875
01011000 088    3.0
01011001 089    3.125
01011010 090    3.25
01011011 091    3.375
01011100 092    3.5
01011101 093    3.625
01011110 094    3.75
01011111 095    3.875
01100000 096    4.0
01100001 097    4.25
01100010 098    4.5
01100011 099    4.75
01100100 100    5.0
01100101 101    5.25
01100110 102    5.5
01100111 103    5.75
01101000 104    6.0
01101001 105    6.25
01101010 106    6.5
01101011 107    6.75
01101100 108    7.0
01101101 109    7.25
01101110 110    7.5
01101111 111    7.75
01110000 112    8.0
01110001 113    8.5
01110010 114    9.0
01110011 115    9.5
01110100 116    10.0
01110101 117    10.5
01110110 118    11.0
01110111 119    11.5
01111000 120    12.0
01111001 121    12.5
01111010 122    13.0
01111011 123    13.5
01111100 124    14.0
01111101 125    14.5
01111110 126    15.0
01111111 127    15.5
10000000 128    -0.0625
10000001 129    -0.06640625
10000010 130    -0.0703125
10000011 131    -0.07421875
10000100 132    -0.078125
10000101 133    -0.08203125
10000110 134    -0.0859375
10000111 135    -0.08984375
10001000 136    -0.09375
10001001 137    -0.09765625
10001010 138    -0.1015625
10001011 139    -0.10546875
10001100 140    -0.109375
10001101 141    -0.11328125
10001110 142    -0.1171875
10001111 143    -0.12109375
10010000 144    -0.125
10010001 145    -0.1328125
10010010 146    -0.140625
10010011 147    -0.1484375
10010100 148    -0.15625
10010101 149    -0.1640625
10010110 150    -0.171875
10010111 151    -0.1796875
10011000 152    -0.1875
10011001 153    -0.1953125
10011010 154    -0.203125
10011011 155    -0.2109375
10011100 156    -0.21875
10011101 157    -0.2265625
10011110 158    -0.234375
10011111 159    -0.2421875
10100000 160    -0.25
10100001 161    -0.265625
10100010 162    -0.28125
10100011 163    -0.296875
10100100 164    -0.3125
10100101 165    -0.328125
10100110 166    -0.34375
10100111 167    -0.359375
10101000 168    -0.375
10101001 169    -0.390625
10101010 170    -0.40625
10101011 171    -0.421875
10101100 172    -0.4375
10101101 173    -0.453125
10101110 174    -0.46875
10101111 175    -0.484375
10110000 176    -0.5
10110001 177    -0.53125
10110010 178    -0.5625
10110011 179    -0.59375
10110100 180    -0.625
10110101 181    -0.65625
10110110 182    -0.6875
10110111 183    -0.71875
10111000 184    -0.75
10111001 185    -0.78125
10111010 186    -0.8125
10111011 187    -0.84375
10111100 188    -0.875
10111101 189    -0.90625
10111110 190    -0.9375
10111111 191    -0.96875
11000000 192    -1.0
11000001 193    -1.0625
11000010 194    -1.125
11000011 195    -1.1875
11000100 196    -1.25
11000101 197    -1.3125
11000110 198    -1.375
11000111 199    -1.4375
11001000 200    -1.5
11001001 201    -1.5625
11001010 202    -1.625
11001011 203    -1.6875
11001100 204    -1.75
11001101 205    -1.8125
11001110 206    -1.875
11001111 207    -1.9375
11010000 208    -2.0
11010001 209    -2.125
11010010 210    -2.25
11010011 211    -2.375
11010100 212    -2.5
11010101 213    -2.625
11010110 214    -2.75
11010111 215    -2.875
11011000 216    -3.0
11011001 217    -3.125
11011010 218    -3.25
11011011 219    -3.375
11011100 220    -3.5
11011101 221    -3.625
11011110 222    -3.75
11011111 223    -3.875
11100000 224    -4.0
11100001 225    -4.25
11100010 226    -4.5
11100011 227    -4.75
11100100 228    -5.0
11100101 229    -5.25
11100110 230    -5.5
11100111 231    -5.75
11101000 232    -6.0
11101001 233    -6.25
11101010 234    -6.5
11101011 235    -6.75
11101100 236    -7.0
11101101 237    -7.25
11101110 238    -7.5
11101111 239    -7.75
11110000 240    -8.0
11110001 241    -8.5
11110010 242    -9.0
11110011 243    -9.5
11110100 244    -10.0
11110101 245    -10.5
11110110 246    -11.0
11110111 247    -11.5
11111000 248    -12.0
11111001 249    -12.5
11111010 250    -13.0
11111011 251    -13.5
11111100 252    -14.0
11111101 253    -14.5
11111110 254    -15.0
11111111 255    -15.5
```

Comment: `f = lambda x:(1-((x&128)>>7)*2)*(16|(x&15))*2.0**(((x&(16|32|64))>>4) - 8)`

Answer (score 0):

## An Optimally Suboptimal Solution

You have grown disillusioned by finding optimal policies for heavy-tailed distributions and their "skew you" attitudes. You decide that for this challenge you are putting your foot down and refusing to optimize your policy further if it means having unbalanced errors. In fact, you're so focused on balance that you will only consider median errors - it's the principle of the thing.

### The Challenge

Generate a policy that searches for hidden points on a line segment, \$L\$, where \$L\$ is the interval \$[0, 1]\$. The number of hidden points on \$L\$ is randomly chosen from the set \$\{0, 10\}\$. The position of each point, \$p\$, (if there are any) is drawn randomly from the uniform distribution on \$\{0, 1\}\$. The points are indistinguishable.

The problem is episodic. In each episode you search the line according to your policy. At each step in the episode you may continue to search the line, or you may reset.

To search the line

1. Choose \$x \in[0, 0.9]\$
2. Accrue a cost of \$2^x\$
3. Discover all points where \$0 \leq p \leq x\$

To reset

1. Generate a new line segment
2. Draw a new number of hidden points to place on the line segment
3. If there are any hidden points, place them on the line segment

**An episode ends when your policy has discovered 10 hidden points on the interval \$[0, 0.9]\$.**

Note: Your policy may not use information about the number of hidden points, nor their locations. When resetting, you do not keep any points you have previously found, but you do keep all costs accrued.

This setup is adapted from @graffe's [Cunning Cousin Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251528/114139) problem.

### Scoring

Define a false negative to be when a policy chooses to reset a line segment and there were 10 hidden points on the interval \$[0, 0.9]\$, i.e. it was possible to complete the episode but the policy resets instead.

Define a false positive to be when a policy searches the entire interval \$[0, 0.9]\$, and there were fewer than 10 hidden points on the interval \$[0, 0.9]\$, i.e. it was not possible to complete the episode but the policy searches the entire available line segment.

Your policy's score is the median absolute difference between the number of false negatives and false positives your policy incurs over one million episodes. The score should be minimized.

$$\text{Score} = median(\lvert FN - FP \rvert)$$

Where \$FN\$ and \$FP\$ are vectors of length one million, and the nth element of each vector is the number of false negatives / positives the policy made in episode n.

If two policies have the same score, the one with the lower median cost from searching lines will rank higher.

---

## Meta

I'm hoping to encourage some custom optimization methods with this one by asking for solutions that are not optimal with respect to the cost function, and by making the objective multi-criteria (because the tie-breaking cost of searching is a function of FN and FP). I think that the way points are discovered prevents optimizing with the cost = x from being equivalent to solving this one, but I haven't exhaustively tested it.

I'd especially appreciate feedback on whether this is an interesting / productive variation on the original version, and whether or not the optimization task is equivalent to a trivial formulation.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement the Hamming algorithm

[Hamming error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) is a form of linear error-correction code which can detect and repair small errors in its input. Your job is to implement a program that, given an input of a sequence of bytes, encodes them using Hamming error correction and outputs the results.

### The algorithm

*Taken from Wikipedia, with some slight modifications*

1. Number all of the bits, starting from 1
2. Write these numbers in binary
3. Every bit position that is a power of 2 (has only one 1 bit in its binary position) is a parity bit, with the remaining bits being data bits.
4. Set every parity bit with the values of every data bit where the bitwise AND of the parity bit's position and the data bit's position is nonzero

You may choose any parity (even or odd) but must state it in your answer.

### Examples

These will use hexadecimal to represent the data.

```
0x1234 -> 0x2a3a1
0x4321 -> 0x8b28e
0xbadf00d -> 0x2f5be8064
```

Comment: [Possible dupe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123219/78410)

Answer (score 0):

[Cut along the lines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252303/cut-along-the-lines)

Answer (score 0):

## [Which weekday was it?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it)

Comment: what span of years do we have to account for

Comment: only between 2000 to 2022. if you want it widened, i can do so

Comment: I think I'll leave out the suggested algorithm as people will use their own ideas for sure. However, I'll add a sentence discouraging built-ins - sth like "if you're using a built-in, consider adding a non-buit-in approach as well". Regarding the year span, i think a narrow one is a good idea, as we avoid problems with changing calendars etc.

Comment: Since you posted the question, the convention is to remove the content here and replace it with a link to the code golf post.

Comment: Oh right, forgot that

Answer (score 0):

## [Show a balanced binary tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253639/show-a-balanced-binary-tree)

Comment: this is [tag:ascii-art] tag. also, can we output via [tag:graphical-output] instead?

Comment: @Steffan I think that would be a meaningfully different challenge, so no.

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:open-ended-function]

Answer (score 0):

## [Best Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257097/best-iterated-prisoners-dilemma-move)

Comment: this is a great idea. an example would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Lengthy numbers type B : remove some occurrences of length

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Given a non negative integer number tell if it can be erased by repeatedly removing **some non overlapping occurrences** of the length of that number from it.

- Like [lengthy numbers type A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254625/84844) erasing means remove all digits.
  For example the number *4440* is not lengthy B because after removing three 4's you obtain *0* which cannot be erased.
  Neither the numbers *50022* and *50044* are lengthy  B because you first remove 5 obtaining *0022* and *0044*, which cannot be erased because of leading 0's.

***Example with selection of some matches***

```
151151599995515 has 15 digits and 4 15's in it  
xx115xx99995515 if you remove 1st and 3rd 15's  
11599995515 : remove 11  
599995515 : remove 9's
55515 : remove 5's
1 and finally remove 1
```

You can choose to remove almost all combinations of 2 15's but if you remove the 2nd and 3rd 15's you get stuck.
151<s>1515</s>99995515
15199995515 -> 11 is no more available!

If you remove a number of 15's different than 2 you get stuck too.

***Example with overlapping***

4444<s>111111</s>1 -> falsy because you can remove only 3 11's and not all 1's like you could if removing overlapping matches were allowed.

44411111111 -> falsy because if you remove all 11's you get 444.
If instead you remove 3 11's you get 44411 which is falsy too.

## Test cases

Truthy

```
1, 12, 21, 22, 123, 321, 322, 331, 333, 4441, 4444, 12345, 987654321, 3610106226, 1010101010, 11111111111, 11131111311, 151151599995515, 10812816208148888188, 82428208832101683082414123828341883888, 1515515551555515555515555551555555155555155551555155151, 999199999915999991599999999915999915999999919399999999991915999999999999999999999915999999929999999, 10121111011011011011011011011011011012110110110121101110110121111011123101101101101121011011110110111, 15101251011012229752519101110101010101010111111101101101101101111011011011011110111101101101101101915, 2020220202202022020220202232020220202202022020223220232020222220220222202202202202202202202202202202202220223202202202202202202202202222022022022022022022222202202202202202222022022022022022023876543213
```

Falsy

```
0, 2, 9, 10, 11, 23, 100, 233, 444, 1224, 4440, 50022, 50044, 1101010101, 4444111110, 44441111111, 44411111111, 121666626162, 181811818128181818, 127271272722672224724122727122712242722472727272722472727272247272127272, 3919555395539111955255533922519455392511539551925395511,   
 1001023010023100160010010010010061110250100123001001001230061001010100102370100610016001001001110230, 1241242212412241241241241241241241241241241241141624124114241241241242612412412416241222412411424221241244124142412412144124, 108484298442981044294284942984429844294291042942942942849429429484284948429484842942942984104842984429429844298448429429429429429429429428494294294842942942948429428484942942942942984429429844284948429428494842849484284942942942942942984484294294284942942942942942942942942942910429429484294294
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard rules apply.

- Input can be given in any convenient method.
- Output any two different values telling if the number is lengthy B or not.

Comment: Not a comment on the challenge itself, but could you use a full-size header (the same formatting as you have for the test cases header) for the challenge title moving forward? It makes Sandbox easier to browse and doesn't give the OSP bot trouble with automatic parsing.

Comment: @Unrelated String how it works now?

Comment: Yep, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

## [Wordle games without repeating letters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256363/73593)

Given a word list, find all sets of five words of five letters each, such that the words of each set have 25 distinct letters in total.

This challenge was inspired by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c33AZBnRHks&t=1424s) video by Matt Parker.

#### Example

`TODO`

#### Rules

- Standard I/O rules apply.
- Words contain only lowercase (or alternatively, uppercase) alphabetic characters.
- You can assume there are no empty words (i.e. words of length zero).
- The input can contain words that cannot belong to any set that satisfies the property, such as words with less then five letters, words with more than five letters, and words with repeated letters.

### Scoring

This challenge wants to be an experimental mix of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).

If your solution has:

- a [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of \$\Omega(f(n))\$ (see [Big Omega notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation)) where
  \$f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N\$
  is a function of the form
  $$f(n) =
  (\log_2 \log_2 n)^{k_{-2}}
  \cdot (\log_2 n)^{k_{-1}}
  \cdot n^{k_0}
  \cdot 2^{k_1}
  \cdot 2^{(2^{k_2})}
  \cdot \ldots
  $$
  where \$n\$ the the total number of the letters of the words in the input;
- a length of \$x\$ bytes (or whatever unit of measurement is commonly used in the language of your choice);

then the score is \$f(x + 4)\$. Lowest score wins!

###### Notes

- obviously, infinitely many terms \$k_i\$ can be \$0\$;
- terms with three or more \$\log\$ (e.g. \$\log_2 \log_2 \log_2 n\$) cannot be used in function \$f\$ because they could be used to arbitrarily lower the score, unless we introduce further complex scoring rules (and most probably they won't be used as a real lower bound).

###### Scoring example

If your solution has a length of \$37\$ bytes, and it has a time complexity of \$\Omega(n^5)\$, then it has a score of \$(37+4)^5\$.

Edit: scoring rules postponed for a future challenge

Comment: can we assume that there will be at least one solution in the input?

Comment: I didn't think about it. In which case this assumption can be useful?

Comment: I think that since the number of distinct five-letter words is constant, any algorithm taking a subset of them would be constant time. So, once you filter out words that not five letters long and de-duplicate, the complexity of the rest of the algorithm doesn't matter. Having the length "5" instead be a parameter could address this.

Comment: assuming at least one solution avoids the "no solutions" edge case, which (depending on algorithm) may require extra code to handle logic that the bulk of the code doesn't handle. Example: if i have a loop which doesn't stop until i've seen some N>0 eligible words, it would run into an infinite loop in the "no solutions" scenario. Considering you have to output all solutions, however, I can see how it might not make a huuge difference. It's up to you tbh :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Minimum rotation to get the maximum value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253529/minimum-rotation-to-get-the-maximum-value)

Comment: Can you take the input as a list `a b d c` (or `a c d b`)?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Speed Checkers KOTH

---

For this King of the Hill challenge, your bot will play checkers against an opponent. However, you should be careful when making complex calculations, because both sides have a limited amount of time to play! Each side will start with 1,000,000 cycles [or 1 second, depending on what I use for the API] to spend during their turn, and if this runs out they will lose the game.

---

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [checkers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkers)

---

This is my attempt at making a KOTH challenge where your runtime matters.

Before I do the rest of the write-up, is the concept good? Is the amount of time given right? Should I use a simpler game? Should the API be in an assembly language, or in a Java runner?

Comment: I'm not certain but I thought checkers (draughts) was solved. It might not fit well in an answer, but once could just hardcode every possibility and play perfectly instantly. I think you need to pick a slightly more complicated game to make this work.

Comment: Yes, it's solved, but you're not going to fit the entire move table in an SE answer. Solving it took I think years of calculation, so that's also off the table.

Answer (score 0):

[Subleq image decoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254034/subleq-image-decoder)

^^ edited 2022.11.03.

Comment: Welcome to Codegolf, and thanks for using the Sandbox! As it is, this isn't a great way to present your challenge. There is no way for the reader to know what they should be optimising for without downloading your archive and reading through the source code. There are a few other points of confusion: does the submission have to work for any image or just the reference, what incentive is there to compress the image if the score is [tag:code-golf], and are we supposed to submit a compression and a decompression program?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thank you for your feedback. 1. Task is exactly as I presented it: make smallest `image.slif` file, which is approved by test program. Nothing more. 2. I know that style of my challenge is unusual, it is made intentionally: it is part of the task to understand how to make such file. Test program is only 104 lines, I think it will be easy to undertand what it is doing. Even if reader do not know C#. 3. As I said, `reference.bin` should not be changed, original image is part of test program in other words.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I modified text to make it more clear what is needed to be done.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman regarding tags: should I change `code-golf` to `code-challenge`? I still think that my challenge is more related to `code-golf` category, but at the same time I do not want to upset people who like competition between languages (which my challenge do not allows).

Comment: Based on what you've said, you should make this [tag:code-challenge] and highlight the scoring more explicitly. I still think this would be much better received if you explained what constituted a successful compression. Just because you've done it intentionally doesn't mean it improves the challenge.

Comment: @sʨɠɠan, @ fryamtheeggman, @ lyxal, @ mousetail, @ xnor, @ kevin-cruijssen, @ arnauld, I removed part of the challenge because of your requirements. Are "details or clarity" problems resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

## A Number Sequence with Everything

### *Work in Progress*

*Watch [Numberphile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBU9E-ZOZAI) featuring Neil Sloane to learn more.*

...

This is sequence A342585 in the OEIS.

> If you like the oddly self-referential nature of this sequence, check out Van Eck's/Look and Say sequence (insert CGCC and Numberphile links here.)

> This is one of those unconventional self-referential sequences. If you're intrigued, check out Van Eck's/Look and Say sequence (insert CGCC and Numberphile links here.)

$$
\begin{align}
& 0_0\\
& 1_0 \quad 1_1 \quad 0_2\\
& 2_0 \quad 1_1 \quad 2_2 \quad 0_3 \\
& 3_0 \quad 2_1 \quad 4_2 \quad 1_3 \quad 1_4 \quad 0_5 \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
0_0 \;\cdot \;1_0 \quad 1_1 \quad 0_2 \;\cdot\; 2_0 \quad 1_1 \quad 2_2 \quad 0_3 \;\cdot\;3_0 \quad 2_1 \quad 4_2 \quad 1_3 \quad 1_4 \quad 0_5
$$

$$
0^0 \;\cdot \;0^1 \quad 1^1 \quad 2^0 \;\cdot\; 0^2 \quad 1^1 \quad 2^2 \quad 3^0 \;\cdot\;0^3 \quad 1^2 \quad 2^4 \quad 3^1 \quad 4^1 \quad 5^0
$$

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.
- [Sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) apply.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Comment: In the OEIS community, the name "inventory sequence" has been introduced for this sequence. This should also be stated in the description. The A-number of the sequence should be given as a link. The name is inappropriate in my opinion. "with everything" is more appropriate for a pizza order, and in the now more than 350,000 OEIS sequences there are many more candidates that could be considered for such an attribute depending on the viewer's taste.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It *is* called the inventory sequence, and not only within OEIS. That was the other name I was considering for the question. The "with everything" name comes verbatim from the Numberphile video. I agree that it's dramatic and clickbaity, and I'm open to changing it. I think this name is appropriate too, though, since it's meant to attract the people who watch that Numberphile video and come looking for the sequence. I think there's a sizable overlap as whenever there's a new sequence video on Numberphile, we have a corresponding CGCC challenge posted within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

## Minimum Overlapping Points in Continuous Line Drawing

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

A [contour drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_drawing) is a type of drawing that is made of only one continuous line, meaning that the drawing utensil cannot leave the paper until the drawing is done. For the purposes of this challenge, we will only be using horizontal and vertical lines for the drawing utensil's movement from start to finish.

Your task is, given an 8x8 image representing  a continuous line drawing, output the minimum number of overlapping points needed to draw the image continuously.

For example, for this image:

[image]

The minimum number of overlapping points needed is 2 because it can be drawn like this, with the red points marking overlapping points:

[image]

There is no way to draw it without overlapping points twice or more.

### Rules

- You can take the input in any convenient format, including as a matrix, list, image file, or ASCII art. You will need to specify what this expected input format is in your answer.
- Output can be in any convenient format.
- For every "step" of the drawing, the drawing utensil can only go left, right, up, or down for the purposes of this challenge.
- Points that are overlapped on more than once are counted as extra overlapped points. (Thus the first test case outputs 3, not 2 for overlapping on the center twice)
- You may assume that the input is valid and can be drawn with a continuous line.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| [image] `........` `..@.....` `..@.....` `..@.....` `@@@@@@@.` `..@.....` `........` `........` | 3 |
| [image] `........` `...@....` `...@....` `..@@@@@@` `...@....` `...@....` `...@....` `........` | 3 |
| [image] `@@@@@@@@` `@......@` `@......@` `@......@` `@......@` `@......@` `@......@` `@@@@@@@@` | 0 |
| [image] `@@@@@@@@` `@......@` `@......@` `@......@` `@@@@@@@@` `@......@` `@......@` `@@@@@@@@` | 0 |
| [image] `@@@@....` `@..@....` `@..@....` `@@@@@@@@` `...@...@` `...@...@` `...@...@` `...@@@@@` | 0 |
| [image] `..@@@@@@` `..@....@` `@@@@@@.@` `@.@..@.@` `@.@@@@@@` `@....@..` `@....@..` `@@@@@@..` | 1 |
| [image] `........` `.@@@@@..` `.@.@.@..` `.@@@@@..` `.@.@.@..` `.@@@@@..` `........` `........` | 4 |
| [image] `@@@@@@@@` `@.@@@@.@` `@.@@@@.@` `@@@@@@@@` `@@.@@.@@` `@@....@@` `@@@@@@@@` `@@@@@@@@` | 0 |
| [image] `........` `..@.@...` `.@@@@@..` `..@.@...` `.@@@@@..` `..@.@...` `........` `........` | 7 |

### Meta

- Are there any similar questions to this?
- What would be some good tags to add?
- Should I make the task to only find whether the input is possible without any overlapping?
- Should there be an animation as explanation for the minimum overlapping points for each test case?

Answer (score 0):

**Lengthy numbers type C : remove one occurrece at time**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

A non negative integer number is a  *lengthy number type C* if it can be erased by repeatedly removing **only one** occurrence of the length of the number from it.

- Erasing means cancel all the digits.

For simplicity and allowing different approaches we restrict the input to a number up to 11 digits length or in other words in the range [0..98765432111]

- Numbers less than 13 digits are guaranteed to have only one possible outcome while from 13 digits they require branches during the process because there can be overlaps.
  For example a 13 digits number *1139138765421* require to test both 13's in it because removing one instead of the other will give different results.
- Numbers less than 12 digits are permutations of all the lengths in each step ( if they are lengthy C ) while from 12 digits there can be embedded lengths, for example 112087654321 has 12 inside 10.

**Examples**

```
123  -> remove 3
12   -> remove 2
1    -> remove 1 -> erased

133  -> remove 3
13   -> no 2 -> not a lengthy C

302  -> remove 3
02   -> remove 2
0    -> not a lengthy C
```

## Test cases

Truthy

```
1, 12, 21, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321, 1234, 4321, 42513, 635241, 3476251, 743986215, 3657211084, 11123456789, 11987654321
```

Falsy

```
0, 2, 3, 10, 11, 13, 20, 103, 133, 300, 301, 302, 303, 310, 322, 399, 1233, 1240, 3419, 4000, 632644, 1111111, 80000001, 1010101010, 10987654321, 1008765432, 11108765432, 11098765432, 11111111111
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard rules apply.

- Input can be given by any convenient method.
- Output any two different values telling if the number is a lengthy number type C or not.

Answer (score 0):

## LS, Part 1: Ana Gram [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

**Warning**: Wouldn't you rather answer a challenge about ponies?<sup>1</sup>

---

If you have read *The Hostile Hospital*, you would know that the Baudelaire orphans, from one of the scraps of paper recovered from the Quagmire's notebooks, they discover a name, "Ana Gram". Later on,  they realize that means the word "anagram", not a name. And that information helps them in finding out who Count Olaf disguised Violet Baudelaire as (Laura V. Bleediotie). They have to search through the entire hospital list, but trace the correct person down. However, what if they lived in a time where YOU helped them? Not personally, but with a program?

So your task today is simple. Given a string `a` and an array, return a smaller array that contains all the possible anagrams of `a`.

### Rules:

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins
- Make sure to lowercase everything in the array and the string
- Two strings that are the same are not anagrams
- Make sure to watch out for initials! You should also remove them
- There may be multiple possible anagrams. Output them all

### Test cases:

```
String, Array 
-> Array

"Violet", ["Veilo","Efh", "Telvio","veliot"]
-> ["Telvio","veliot"]

"Krotasmon", ["Krota","Monsakrot", "Trokasmont","KROTASMON"]
-> ["Monsakrot"]

"Laura V. Bleediotie", ["Violet Baudelaire", "Violet. Baudelaire", "VIOLeT BAUDELAIRE", "BUADELIAR VIOLETM", "Laura V. Bleediotie"]
-> ["Violet Baudelaire", "Violet. Baudelaire", "VIOLeT BAUDELAIRE"]
```

#### META:

Does the array part still qualify this as a dupe?

<sub>1: Inspired by the "all rights reserved" page of LS: The Unauthorized Autobiography</sub>

Comment: There are a few other anagram challenges, but most of them seem to be just comparing two strings: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74164/31625), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1294/31625). Your rule about two strings being the same not being an anagram is pretty surprising. You should probably have a test case that includes that behaviour, or remove the rule.

Answer (score 0):

## Implement Casio's M [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

[Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254710/107017)

Comment: You should probably have a test case where double-digit (or more) numbers are used and require proper parsing. For your case, only reading the `0` in each number will still give the correct answer.

Comment: Additionally, I realised you don't have a case using `M-` properly, or an output that is negative. Also, what happens if the input is something like `9M+9MM+`? Or `9M+MMM+`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks! I have updated the test cases and the specifications. As for those two test cases, I have tested them on my dinosaur Casio machine and while `9M+9MM+` is valid, but `9M+MMM+` is not because of `MM`, so I have changed specs to let both of them be valid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Intermediate Boolean Algebra Calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254719/intermediate-boolean-algebra-calculator)

Answer (score 0):

## Getting over it with the space Cabbage, Wolf, Goat

[Posted!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254746/interstellar-cabbages-wolves-and-sheep)

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes instead of normal ones? That will make the examples very hard to copy paste

Comment: @mousetail. I’m sorry, but what are smart quotes?

Comment: The fancy quotes instead of the normal straight ones. You can see the left and right ones are different. Most programing languages have difficulty parsing text that contains special quotes.

Comment: @mousetail Oh, I see. My iPad just does that, will fix

Answer (score 0):

## [1 to N column and row sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254768/1-to-n-column-and-row-sums)

Answer (score 0):

**Four Candles**

There is a tradition in Germany to have an Adventskranz in the run up to Christmas. This is basically four candles. One is lit each Sunday during advent (including the ones from the last Sundays) up until Christmas. This gave me an idea for an ASCII art challenge (we haven't had many of those recently).

The challenge: Reproduce the burning of the candles exactly as shown below.

```
  ||     ||     ||     ||   
 ____   ____   ____   ____
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|____| |___ | |____| |____|

         ||     ||     ||   
  ()    ____   ____   ____
 ____  |    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|____| |___ | |____| |____|

                ||     ||   
         ()    ____   ____
  ()    ____  |    | |    |
 ____  |    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    | |    |
|____| |___ | |____| |____|

                       ||   
                ()    ____
         ()    ____  |    |
  ()    ____  |    | |    |
 ____  |    | |    | |    |
|____| |___ | |____| |____|

                       ()
                ()    ____
         ()    ____  |    |
  ()    ____  |    | |    |
______ |___ | |____| |____|
```

The rules: Very simple really...no input required, any amout of trailing newlines or spaces alowed as long as the output looks exactly as above. Please feel free to show each stage as a different frame and clear the screen between each but this is not a requirement. Simply printing (or retuning from a function) what is shown above is fine. Oh and also, this is ASCII art...printing or returning a list of lines is not good enough.

This is code golf. The shortest answer in any language will earn respect and I'm sure some upvotes. There will be no accepted answer so feel free to join in. The more languages the better no matter how long the answer is, as long as it is a best effort to make it as short as possible (golfed).

Answer (score 0):

## Cistertian Numerals

[Cistercian numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cistercian_numerals) are a method of representing any integer from 1 to 9,999 in a single "glyph".

### Input

Any Integer, 1..9999

### Output

An image or binary array (any standard accepted format) of the glyph representing the Input, in the form shown on the Wiki article - e.g. [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cistercian_numerals#/media/File:Cistercian_digits_(vertical).svg)

### Examples

If using an array, it seems to me that all combinations should fit into a 6hx5w grid - e.g:

9999:

```
xxxxx
x x x
xxxxx
xxxxx
x x x
xxxxx
```

5555:

```
xxxxx
 xxx
  x
  x
 xxx
xxxxx
```

7643:

```
  x
 xxx
x x x
  x
x x x
xxx x
```

Comment: [Very closed related, if not a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216166/66833)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing you're right. Is it too close to be a worthwhile challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## [Make the cheapest cut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255069/11261)

Comment: I suggest allowing also outputting **all** cuts if there are ties, not just any; or guaranteeing unique solution (this is my personal preference, but I understand other views on that matter). Re 2.: Yes, some test-cases would be nice.

Comment: @pajonk Good feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Find the box by its corners](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255133/find-the-box-by-its-corners)

Answer (score 0):

## [Write a program that prints a program that's almost quine.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255302/106959)

Comment: So basically, we write a program, which given `n`, prints a program which prints its own first `n` characters, which are also the first `n` characters of all other programs that can be outputted? And the program has to be irreducible?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Correct.

Comment: What should the program do if input number is greater than its length? For example, my program has only 10 bytes, and i got an input 100.

Comment: Maybe you should define what irreducible is in your question.

Comment: @tsh The challenge is already uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

## Denoise a image [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

There are various de-noising algorithms available. This question focuses on a specific one that preserves sharp edges but is also very simple to implement.

Take 2 parameters, `r` and `k`, and a grayscale image.

For every pixel, draw a `r` by `r` square around it and select all pixels inside.

```
 r=1   r=3     r=5
              #####
       ###    #####
  p    #p#    ##p##
       ###    #####
              #####
```

Find the `k` pixels in this area that are closest to the source pixel in terms of absolute color difference.

Replace each pixel with the median of the `k` closest pixels in it's area. Include the pixel itself in it's area. If there are less than `k` closest pixels take all of them. This can happen for pixels near the edge.

*Note: If `r==0` or `k==1` this will return the image unchanged*

`r` is always odd.

### Test Cases

```
In    K    R    Out
-------------------
000             000
010   1    1    010
000             000
-------------------
000             000
010    3    3   000
000             000
-------------------
000             000
010    3    3   010
100             100
-------------------
000             000    000
010    5    3   010 OR 010 since the median is tied
101             000    101
-------------------
12345           
23451
34512  5    5
45123
51234
-------------------
```

### IO

Take input as either a image file or as a 2 dimensional array of integers between 0 and 255. Output in the same format.

Comment: The input requirements are not clear to me - what do you mean by a "greyscale image"? An image file? A matrix of floats from [0-1]? An integer matrix (as suggested by test-cases)?

Answer (score 0):

## [Find the representative submatrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255333/find-the-representative-submatrix)

Answer (score 0):

## Is It a Flat 3D Quadrilateral?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [3d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d)

Your task is to write a program or function that, given a collection of four 3D points with Cartesian coordinates, outputs whether the shape formed by connecting those points is a flat 3D quadrilateral (i.e. all the points are coplanar).

### Rules

- The input will always have 4 points.
- Each shape will be formed by connecting the points with lines in the order they were given and then back to the first point. You may assume that no two of these lines will intersect each other and that no three consecutive points will be collinear.
- For each point \$(x, y, z)\$, \$x\$, \$y\$, and \$z\$ will all be integers within the range \$[0,8]\$.
- You may choose any two distinct values to represent a truthy and falsy output, as long as it is consistent. Input can be in any convenient format.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| (0, 0, 0) (0, 1, 0) (1, 2, 0) (1, 0, 0) | true |
| (0, 0, 0) (0, 1, 0) (0, 0, 1) (1, 0, 0) | false |
| (0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 0) (1, 1, 1) (0, 1, 1) | true |
| (0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 6) (7, 8, 5) (4, 3, 2) | false |
| (1, 1, 1) (2, 2, 2) (1, 3, 2) (2, 4, 5) | false |
| (0, 4, 8) (4, 8, 4) (8, 4, 0) (4, 0, 4) | true |

### Meta

- Any additional test case suggestions?

Comment: I suggest that the input has exactly 4 points. The main approach will be anyway to check if the fourth point is coplanar with other 3, and then the fifth and so on, so maybe stick to the first task not to lose the main focus of the challenge?

Comment: @pajonk That makes sense; I will change that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rolling a 1x1x2 block](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255366/rolling-a-1x1x2-block)

Answer (score 0):

### Balanced Candy Distribution

There are 4 piles with 12 pieces of candy each, for a total of 48 pieces, and there are 12 kids to split that candy with, each kid will receive exactly 1 piece of candy from each pile, each piece of candy has a unique number on it, from 0 to 47, the candies with numbers 0 through 11 are on one pile, candies number 12 through 23 are on another, candies 24 through 35 are on a pile, and the last pile is candies 36 to 47. Candy #0 tastes amazing, and candy #47 tastes not so great, so to make it fair, each kid’s 4 candies should add up to the same number (which should be 94), there is an issue though, there are an unknown number of different flavors of candy, completely independent of their tastiness, and it would be unfair if Timmy was to, by bad luck, have all his 4 pieces of candy end up being cinnamon flavored, so, we introduce the idea of “Unfairness points”. For each kid, if we match each of their four candy pieces to their other three candies, for each pairing if both candies are the same flavor, we add one unfairness point, to illustrate this, let’s imagine a smaller example, with only four kids and 16 candies, if Timmy got 4 cinnamon candies, Laura got 1 cinnamon candy, 1 vanilla candy, and 2 chocolate candy, Johnny got 2 vanilla candies and 2 caramel candies, and Sam got 3 cinnamon candy and 1 strawberry candy, this arrangement would receive 12 unfairness points: 6 from Timmy, 1 from Laura, 2 from Johnny, and 3 from Sam.

*Your code must output the arrangement* that satisfies the two restrictions set forth in the beginning (each kid receives a single candy from each pile, and that for each kid all of their four candies add up to 94) *that has the fewest unfairness points*, if there is more than one arrangement that is tied for least number of unfairness points, you must output the list of all of those arrangements given a list of all the candies. This input could be formatted in any way that is convenient, but preferably something resembling a list of strings, where the index is the number of the candy and the string is the flavor, for example, in python, a valid input format would be

```
[“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Apple”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Caramel”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Apple”,“Apple”,“Caramel”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Apple”,“Sour”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Apple”,“Sour”,“Pear”,“Pear”,“Caramel”,“Vanilla”,“Vanilla”,“Vanilla”,“Apple”,“Sour”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Avocado”,“Apple”,“Sour”,“Pear”,“Pear”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Caramel”]
```

Or it could also be already separated into the piles

```
[[“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”,“Apple”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Caramel”,“Chocolate”,“Vanilla”,“Chocolate”],[“Apple”,“Ap...
```

Or it could include the number itself, if you wanted

```
[[0,“Chocolate”],[1,“Chocolate”],[2,“Chocolate”],[3,“Vanilla”],[4,“Chocolate”],[5,“Apple”],[6,“Chocola...
```

The output can be given in any way that makes it easy to interpret what the numbers of the candies each kid should get, for example, in python, an output like

```
[[0,19,30,45],[9,14,28,43],[5...
```

Is totally fine, and anything that is easy or understandable like that is fine.

This is code-golf and so lowest bytes wins

---

Sandbox questions:

- English is my second language, is this written clearly enough?
- Would it be better if it was generalized? As in "There are N piles with C pieces of candy each, for a total of N*C pieces, and there are C kids to split that candy with, each kid will receive exactly 1 piece of candy from each pile..."
- Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

## Tell 32-bit from 64-bit with most disallowed bytes

Decide an integer N. Take an array of length N, and output a x86 opcode, which when running, reach different position after leaving the opcode you provided.

- No bytes given in input is allowed in your output.
- You'll be in Ring 3, so some x86 features can't be used.
- You can destroy all available registers, including XMM, x87, etc.
- You can assume 4096 bytes of available stack under stack pointer.
- It's not necessary a `jmp`. Other ways to reach different position are fine.
- The destination should be in 256 bytes before your code or in 256 bytes after your code. `jmp .+0xEBEBEBEB` is not allowed unless your output is at least ~336859924 bytes.
- Each destination should have at least 2 bytes of space to fit a `jmp short` instruction.

Here is a possible program with N=0:

```
([])=>[0x66, 0x40, 0x3D]
```

Assuming this program is loaded into 0, then in 32-bit mode, it goes to 7; in 64-bit mode, it goes to 5, both of which have enough space.

This is an example with N=1:

```
([x])=>x==0x66||x==0x41||x==0x3D?[0x24,0x00,0x40,0x74,0x74]:[0x66,0x41,0x3D]
```

Largest N wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Title Case (WIP)

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Input a string with letters and spaces, input a set of mirror words. Output a string which is title case of the input string that follow the following rules:

1. Cases is unchanged for any words already contains uppercase letters;
2. Cases is unchanged for any words in the set mirror words AND is not the first word;
3. For all other words, the first letter is changed into uppercase

The set mirror words is an input to your program / function. Here are mirror words used in testcases:

```json
["a", "an", "and", "as", "as", "at", "but", "by", "for", "if", "in", "nor", "of", "off", "on", "or", "per", "so", "the", "to", "up", "via", "yet"]
```

### Testcases

```
Input -> Output
the sun and the moon -> The Sun and the Moon
jQuery tutorial using jQuery plugins -> jQuery Tutorial Using jQuery Plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

A map maps keys(string) to values(string). Basic operations includes:

- Set. Given a key and a value, store it.
- Get. Given a key, get the last value stored into this key, or `""`(empty string) if nothing ever stored into.

For some reason, sometimes keys looks same but need to refer to different object. Therefore, color is introduced. Provided keys is therefore splitted, and to get colored key, color each part of keys, and concat them.

For example, say `a` is colored red, then

- `a` is \$\color{red}a\$
- `aa` is \$aa\$
- `a a` is \$\color{red}{aa}\$
- `ab` is \$ab\$
- `a b` is \$\color{red}{a}b\$

Therefore, another operation is

- Color. Given a keypart, resign its color. Color is a non-negative integer and default to 0.

Shortest code in each languages wins.

Test cases

```javascript
[[GET, "a"],         // ""
 [SET, "a", "1"],
 [GET, "a"],         // "1"
 [COL, "a", 1],
 [GET, "a"],         // ""
 [SET, "a bb", "2"],
 [GET, "a b b"],     // "2"
 [COL, "a", 0],
 [GET, "a"]]         // "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solve the "/" puzzles from Taiji

*Spoilers for the game Taiji, it's really good you should play it*

Taiji puzzles consist of a rectangular grid, a solution consists of setting each square to either on or off:

```
####
#...
##..
```

However, not every solution is correct, a puzzle can contain any number of colored slashes, here represented by numbers:

```
....
1...
..1.
....
```

A *shape* is defined as a contiguous area that all has the same state. (either on or off). Areas with the same color slash must have the same shape, but it may be rotated (but **not** mirrored). For example, if you have this:

```
1..1.
.22.1
1..1.
```

A solution would be:

```
.#.#.
##..#
.#.#.
```

Note that all 1s are a single square while both 2s are a T shape, in this case in opposite colors.

Note that the number must be in the same place in every shape, so if you have this puzzle:

```
.....
1..1.
.....
```

This would **Not** be valid:

```
#..##
..##.
#..##
```

Because one 1 is in the tip and the other is in the tail.

If the numbers are **different** the shapes **must** be different. However, they count as different if the number is in a different part of the shape.

A shape can contain multiple numbers. If it contains the same number twice that means the shape must be irrationally symmetric.

Your challenge is: Given a number, output a possible solution. Note: There will always be at least 2 possible solutions, since the inverse of any valid solution is also valid.

### Test Cases

Note many of these have many valid solutions.

```
1..1.            #..#.
.22.1        --> ....#
1..1.            #..#.

....              ##..
123.          --> #.##
....              #.##


...               #.#
111           --> #.#
...               #.#

1.22.1            ##..##
......            ######
2....2        --> .####.
2....2            .####.
......            ######
1.22..            ##..##

3....             #####
11211         --> ..#..
3....             #####

....              #.#.
111.          --> #.#.
....              #.#.
```

You may take input as a 2d list of numbers, and use any constant value to represent a cell that does not create a hint (eg. 0). For output you may also use any 2 constant values to represent on and off.

Comment: Is mirrored same?

Answer (score 0):

## Optimize your score on a biased multiple choice test

In a multiple choice test, sometimes, by chance, multiple questions in a row will have the same answer. Some of my teachers dislike this, and will change questions to ensure there are never more than \$n\$ of the same answer in a row.

In this challenge, for each question in a test, you'll be given a set of four confidence values from `0` to `1`, which sum to `1`. These represent the odds of each choice being correct (for example, `[0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1]` if you're 60% sure that B is correct, 20% sure C is correct, and 10% sure either of the others could be right). You'll also be given a positive integer `n`, the maximum number of same-answer questions in a row.

Given this information, you must output the set of answers that would give you the highest estimated score.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushing boxes away](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257057/pushing-boxes-away) but [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)

I'll accept first fastest algorithm and then this challenge turns into [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Sandbox Notes

- Some options are listed in comment

Comment: Upvote this comment if this idea of question is good

Comment: Upvote this comment if this idea of question is bad

Comment: Upvote this comment if this way of handling [tag:fastest-algorithm] is good

Comment: Upvote this comment if this way of handling [tag:fastest-algorithm] is bad

Answer (score 0):

## A randomly colored walk

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)

Given two inputs, a distance \$d\$ and a number \$n\$ output \$n\$ random colors which each have distance \$d\$ from the previous.

### Background

A [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) is a path which is defined by choosing a random direction and (usually) fixed distance to go at each step. We will be taking a random walk through the RGB color space using [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) as our metric.

### The challenge

For this challenge you will take two inputs, \$n\$ and \$d\$. Let \$n\$ be the number of colors to output, this will always be an integer \$1 \leq n\$, and \$d\$ be the distance between consecutive elements, which will always be \$0 \leq d \leq 128\$. You may additionally assume that \$d\$ is an integer.

For each consecutive pair of elements \$(r_1, g_1, b_1), (r_2, g_2, b_2)\$ of the \$n\$ element sequence output, it must be the case that all values are between 0 and 255 inclusive (or \$[0,256)\$ for floats), and the distance between elements must be within 1 of d, that is \$|\sqrt{(r_1-r_2)^2+(g_1-g_2)^2+(b_1-b_2)^2} - d| < 1\$. This should allow one to restrict their output to integers if they so choose. The walk need not be uniform, but it does need to be random. The starting point of the walk should be random as well.

Standard i/o rules apply, input and output can be in any reasonable format. Graphical output is allowed (and encouraged, though I doubt it will be golfy to do so) so long as the order of the sequence is clear.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

For these test cases input is in the order \$n,d\$ and output is \$(r, g, b)\$ as integers. These are some possible results.

```
5, 5 -> (81, 60, 243), (81, 57, 239), (76, 60, 240), (80, 62, 241), (84, 60, 243)
4, 10 -> (163, 89, 77), (162, 83, 85), (166, 75, 79), (166, 82, 87)
4, 50 -> (212, 36, 232), (247, 1, 239), (220, 44, 243), (217, 81, 209)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195032/totally-blind-chess)

Play chess. You can't see the current board, and can only memory two bytes.

Each turn, you're given your current state(initially 0) and opponent's move(a special value if first move in the game). You then output a list of [moves,state] pair, and the first valid one will get used. If no valid move, then you automatically resign.

Aim is obviously win as many games and lose as less as possible.

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

Comment: [This pretty much](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195032/totally-blind-chess)

Answer (score 0):

## [4D rotation matrix to quaternions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258082/110698)

Answer (score 0):

## Ternary 2-input logic gate

### Objective

Given an expression of a ternary 2-input logic gate, pretty-print its truth table.

### Ternary logic and ternary operators

`L`, `E`, and `G` are the truth values of the ternary logic dealt here. They correspond to Haskell's `LT`, `EQ`, and `GT`.

The expression can have two free variables, hence "2-input".

There are four operators that the expression can have: `min`, `max`, `compare`, and `mappend`. (Again, from Haskell.) Their truth tables are:

```
min|L E G
---+-----
L  |L L L
E  |L E E
G  |L E G

max|L E G
---+-----
L  |L E G
E  |E E G
G  |G G G

compare|L E G
-------+-----
L      |E L L
E      |G E L
G      |G G E

mappend|L E G
-------+-----
L      |L L L
E      |L E G
G      |G G G
```

where the first column is for the first argument and the first row is for the second argument.

### I/O format

The input format shall be a nonempty binary tree whose branches are the operator and whose leaves are the free variables and the truth values.

The output format shall be like this:

```
 |L E G
-+-----
L|? ? ?
E|? ? ?
G|? ? ?
```

where `?` is filled with appropriate truth values represented by `L`, `E`, or `G`. Again, the first column is for the first argument and the first row is for the second argument.

### Examples

Let the free variables be `P` and `Q` in sake of demonstration.

Given `P compare (E compare Q)`, the truth table is:

```
 |L E G
-+-----
L|L L E
E|L E G
G|E G G
```

Given `(P min Q) compare (E compare (P max Q))`, the truth table is:

```
 |L E G
-+-----
L|L E E
E|E E E
G|E E G
```

Given `((E compare (P max Q)) compare (P min Q)) mappend (P compare (E compare Q))`, the truth table is:

```
 |L E G
-+-----
L|G L E
E|L E G
G|E G L
```

Given `Q mappend P`, the truth table is:

```
 |L E G
-+-----
L|L L G
E|L E G
G|L G G
```

Answer (score 0):

## [A Fine sequence with fine interpretations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258110/110698)

Answer (score 0):

## [Making one shape out of dissections of another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258393/making-one-shape-out-of-dissections-of-another)

Comment: Can the pieces be rotated and/or flipped?

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, they can be moved, rotated, and flipped, but nothing else. I will clarify in the post.

Comment: Two falsy test cases are actually truthy: https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v8/MTGJKzExkYsLREFYRlxAOikJhUhM5oLIw1QBRcEIKG78/z8A

Comment: @Bubbler Lol f*** i am bad at puzzles

Comment: How am i gonna make the falsey test cases if i can't even make these simple ones lol

Comment: Well, the correct answer here is to write a working code yourself and generate test cases based on it :)

Comment: @Bubbler You overestimate my coding capabilities :(

Answer (score 0):

## Floating-point numbers have errors in addition, oh my!

Given two IEEE double-precision floating-point numbers \$x\$ and \$y\$, output the most accurate IEEE double-precision floating-point approximation of the error that would be caused by performing the floating-point addition \$x + y\$.

As a reminder, an *error* is defined as the approximation subtracted by the exact value.

The inputs must deal with denormal numbers and the negative zero as well. However, infinities and NaNs fall into *don't care* situation.

If the output is zero, its sign doesn't matter.

Comment: *"If either of the operands is an infinity or a NaN, the output shall be NaN"* - what about languages that don't support infinity/NaN.

Comment: I'm thinking their equivalent of 1/0... or maybe just the strings `"NaN"` and `"Infinity"`

Answer (score 0):

## [Draw Parcly Taxel's cutie mark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258642/110698)

Answer (score 0):

## Find the sum of the sub-list with the largest sum

### Challenge

Given a list that contains an integer, a sub-list is a contiguous non-empty sequence of elements within that list.

For example, the list \$[1, 3, -2, 5, -6]\$, has some sub-lists \$[1]\$, \$[3, -2]\$,  \$[3, -2, 5, -6]\$, etc.

Your job today is to find the sum of the sub-list with the largest sum.

For example \$[1, 3, -2, 5, -6]\$, the sum of the sub-list with the largest sum is \$7\$, the sub-list with the largest sum is  \$[1, 3, -2, 5]\$.

### Specification

- Input / Output can be taken in any reasonable format, taking a list of numbers and returning a number, which is the sum of the sub-list with the largest sum
- The input array is guaranteed to have at least one element.

Testcases:

```
[1, 3, -2, 5, -6] -> 7
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4] -> 6
[-3, -6, -8, -1] -> -1
[5, 4, -1, 7, 8] -> 23
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Comment: This is maximum subarray. [Lots of dupes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/138697/110698).

Answer (score 0):

## [Canonical form of a cubic Bézier curve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258605/110698)

Answer (score 0):

[Generating all possible equations with 10 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258710/generating-all-possible-equations-with-10-characters)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, and thanks for using the Sandbox! This looks like an interesting challenge. You'll need to specify a winning criterion; it looks like you're interested in [tag:fastest-code] (code should run as fast as possible), but we normally don't combine that with [tag:restricted-time] (code must take less than an hour to run). [tag:fastest-code] without the 1-hour restriction is one option; [tag:code-golf] + [tag:restricted-time] is another. If you're not sure which to choose, I recommend [tag:code-golf], since it's easier to calculate the score for submissions.

Comment: @DLosc I wanted this "1 hour" part to be just a kind of side note for people to know what to expect regarding the performance. I changed my question to make it seem less like a winning requirement

Comment: You need to objectively specify what does "as fast as possible" mean. See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info and refer to other [tag:fastest-code] challenges for inspirations: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code?sort=votes

Comment: @pajonk is it better? I edited it

Comment: @ordptt for me it would be enough. Also, do I understand "There are no operators in sequence" correctly that this applies only to successive operators like `1*-1`, but `-1+2=1` is ok? What about `1-2=-1` - is this valid? Or `1*(-1)`?

Comment: @pajonk it means that there cannot be any *,+,-,/ adjacent to each other, so I believe you got it right. So `1*-1` is not valid but `-1+2=1`, `1*(-1)` are. `1-2=-1` is not valid because the RHS is negative.

Answer (score 0):

[Generate number from given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258870/generate-number-from-given-range)

Comment: This downvote was too fast :)

Comment: Is the output a floating point number?

Comment: @Jacob It is doesn't matter. For example if your function for inputs `10.55, -1, 1` will output `0` it is fine but if the output will be `0.55` it is also fine. In general the output can not be only integers because at least for range `[0, 1]` you can output integers `0` and `1` only for two different speed of wind, another wind speed must give some number from range `(0, 1)`

Comment: Could you clarify the sentence "and multiply this value to `-1` pseudo randomly"?

Comment: @CommandMaster It is just part of story :) He do it to get the negative numbers too, because of speed of wind can not be negative number

Comment: What's the range of the speed of wind? Can it be any real number?

Comment: "Your function must output different result each time for different wind speed" - I think it may be impossible for some inputs because of floating point inaccuracies (there is in practice only a finite amount of floating point numbers between two integers) - or are we to ignore floating point errors?

Comment: @CommandMaster It can be any `float` or `double` (it is up to you) number which provide your chosen language

Comment: @pajonk Good point. Yes, of course you can ignore floating point errors. I will add it to challenge

Comment: This is a pretty easy challenge but still fairly interesting

Answer (score 0):

## [The topology of origami](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258896/110698)

Answer (score 0):

## Guessing on straws

*Dedicated to Martin Gardner, taken from his book*

### Background

In the old days, the Slavs had such divination. One girl was clutching six straws in her fist, and her friend was pairing first the top and then the bottom ends. If all straws were ring-tagged, the girl would be married.

### Goal of challenge

Having the number of straws and the binding schemes, determine whether the single hole cycle will result.

[image]

### Input

- Number of straws `N`, even integer `>= 2`
- Two nested lists as top and bottom links, for instance `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [6, 3]]`

*Schemes may be valid or invalid!*
*On one hand,* it is guaranteed that are used only positive integers not more `N`;
no self-links (`[1, 1]`), no tautologies (`[[1, 2], [2, 1], …]`), no broken lists (`[[1], [ ], …]`) etc.

Please note, that pairs are unordered, so eg  `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [6, 3]]` and `[[4, 1], [2, 5], [3, 6]]` both valid (and equivalent) schemes.

*But* due to the girl’s inattention, followed cases can take place:

- Missing pair (one or more): `[[1, 4], [6, 3]]`, `[[1, 10], [4, 5], [3, 7]]` etc.
- More than two binding straws: `[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6]]` (and as result, free straws)

All of these inputs are invalid, your program must detect them and stop with appropriate message (see below).

### Output

Any three distinct symbols for "Invalid input", "No loop", "Has loop" cases.
Suitable for golfing on your language:

- `-1` for invalid input, `0` for "No loop", `1` for "Loop"
- `None`, `False` and `True` respectively
  etc.

### Test cases

```
N: 2, TopLinks: [[1, 2]], BottomLinks: [[2, 1]]  → True

N: 4, TopLinks: [[1, 2], [3, 4]], BottomLinks: [[2, 1], [3, 4] ]  → False

N: 4, TopLinks: [[1, 2], [2, 4]], BottomLinks: [[2, 1], [3, 4], [3, 2] ]  → Invalid

N: 8, TopLinks: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 5], [7, 8]], 
BottomLinks: [[8, 1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [7, 6] ]  → True
```

Comment: We usually try to [avoid requiring input validation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/92727), and I feel like in this case it doesn't make the challenge any more interesting. Is there a particular reason you want it? Additionally, I'll suggest allowing other reasonable input formats, for example a list of values from 1 to n/2 where paired indices have the same value.

Comment: @CommandMaster  Well, I thought without validation this is a very simple challenge. But I will take into account your proposal, I will probably remove validation when publishing

Answer (score 0):

## Shortest Code to Implement a Simple Encryption Algorithm

Write a program or function that implements a simple encryption algorithm. The algorithm takes in a string of ASCII characters and a key, and outputs an encrypted string.

### Encryption Algorithm

1. Convert each character in the input string to its ASCII value
2. XOR each ASCII value with the corresponding byte in the key (cycling through the key if necessary)
3. Convert the resulting XOR values back to ASCII characters
4. Concatenate the ASCII characters into a single string and output the result

Your program or function should take in two inputs:

A string of ASCII characters (up to 1024 characters in length)
A key string (up to 1024 characters in length)
Your program or function should output a single string representing the encrypted message.

### Test Cases

```
Input:
message: "Hello World"
key: "secret"
Output:
"UW]cU\xf3M]Z]^Y"

Input:
message: "12345"
key: "password"
Output:
"^%-'$#"

Input:
message: "This is a test message"
key: "key"
Output:
"\x03\x1a\x1c\x17\x02\x0eP\bI\x11\x07\x14N\x1d\x10M\r\b\x1f"
```

This is a codegolf challenge, so the goal is to write the shortest possible implementation of the encryption algorithm. The winner will be determined based on the length of their code, with ties broken by earlier submission time.

Comment: first time with sandbox :/

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207178/xor-two-strings)

Answer (score 0):

## [Mapping Passing Through Point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259074/mapping-passing-through-point)

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something, but this function doesn't seem very well-specified. Since you don't have to handle f(x1) or f(x2), isn't f(x)=y0 allowed?

Comment: @Bbrk24 The image of the function has to be over the whole range -- in other words, for every \$y \in (y_1, y_2)\$, there must be some \$x \in (x_1, x_2)\$, such that \$f(x) = y\$.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'd be a bit more direct about it in the question, then.

Comment: Is it guaranteed \$x_1 < x_0 < x_2\$?

Comment: Do you have to return \$f\$? Can you take \$ x_0, x_1, x_2, y_0, y_1, y_2, x\$ and return \$ f(x) \$ (deterministically)?

Comment: @CommandMaster I thought this is part of the open-ended-function tag, but yeah, you can do it that way.

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes -- and \$y_1 < y_0 < y_2\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Optimize Distance Travelled By Thrown Object (With Air Resistance)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Suppose you're on a flat surface, then throw an object with some velocity \$v_0\$ at an angle \$\theta\$ above the ground. Assuming the only forces on the object are (constant) gravity and air resistance, we can model the horizontal and vertical components of the acceleration (the instantaneous change in velocity in the x and y direction) as follows:

$$a_x = v_x^2 * \delta$$
$$a_y = v_y^2 * \delta + g$$

Where \$v_x\$ and \$v_y\$ are the horizontal and vertical components of velocity, \$g\$ is acceleration due to gravity, and \$\delta\$ is the coefficient of acceleration due to drag (which is a single number which depends on the drag coefficient, cross-sectional area, and the density of the fluid, and the mass).

The initial x and y components of velocity are
$$v_x = v_0 \cos \theta, v_y = v_0 \sin \theta$$

The object stops moving when it hits the ground again (when its \$y\$ position becomes 0 again). We want to **find the angle \$\theta\$ which maximizes the horizontal distance \$x\$ that the object travels.**

Your challenge is, given the initial velocity \$v_0\$, acceleration due to gravity \$g\$, and coefficient of acceleration due to drag \$\delta\$, output the angle \$\theta\$ (in either degrees or radians) which maximizes the horizontal distance travelled, within one percent of the true maximum.

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

**TODO: Test cases**

Comment: Can the person who down-voted explain why?

Answer (score 0):

## Soundproof Cell

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Here's a message from the organizers:

> Hello! We hope this message finds you well.
>
> Unfortunately, your performance in the [past games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259498/) has been sub par. Your team is unimaginative and lacks creativity. Instead of inventing novel techniques to win our games, you keep sticking to [the techniques you know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search). This is not the spirit we would like to encourage in our games.
>
> Tomorrow's game will be very different from what you're used to. To give you some time to prepare, we are telling you the rules in advance.
>
> There are 1000000 balloons whose values [you can download here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huynhtrankhanh/ppcg-soundproof-cell/046db2ab6d8a7e6a26f4ce7a3947fc4a2ae6c6e8/random_numbers.txt). These balloons lie on a straight line. Your job is to pop these balloons in an order to get the most "brownie points".
>
> A balloon may have zero, one or two adjacent balloons. For example, a balloon at the middle of the line has two adjacent balloons. A balloon at the beginning of the line has one adjacent balloon. And if you pop the second balloon, which is the balloon to the right of the first balloon, the balloon at the beginning of the line will have zero adjacent balloons.
>
> When you pop a balloon, the "brownie points" you will get will be equal to the average value of all balloons adjacent to the balloon you pop. If the balloon you pop has no adjacent balloons, you get no points. Remember that when a balloon is popped, it is totally destroyed and you can't pop it again. And no worries, you don't have to pop all the balloons.
>
> We have a pretty intelligent robot here. It is currently partying inside a soundproof cell. Tomorrow it will pop the balloons on your behalf.
>
> The robot, albeit intelligent, has no knowledge of the values of the balloons. It has knowledge of all programming languages in existence. Before the robot pops the balloons, you have to give it some code that when executed, outputs a sequence of balloon indices. You are allowed to use either 0-based or 1-based indices. If after finishing the instructions the robot doesn't get the most "brownie points" possible on your behalf, you are disqualified. But if the robot successfully gets the most "brownie points", your score will be the length of the code you give the robot. The shorter, the better! This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)!

## Summary

- The array of balloon values is fixed in advance.
- You write a program that outputs the optimal sequence of balloons to pop.
- Shortest code wins.

## Tips

- The array of values is randomly generated with a CSPRNG and there is no meaningful way to compress it. However, the sequence of balloons has several important patterns that you can exploit.
- There are many optimal sequences, choose the sequence that is the easiest to compress.
- Remember you don't have to pop all the balloons.
- Your code may be too large to fit in an answer. You can host your code elsewhere, and your answer can contain an explanation of how you come up with the code.

Comment: I think the normal version, where given a list of balloons you output the best popping order, is a lot more interesting than the kologmonov-complexity verison

Comment: Brute force would have a clear advantage over the O(n) solution though. I want to force solvers to come up with an O(n) solution first. The optimal order then has a very clear structure and can be further compressed. The alternative would be to set a fastest-code challenge, but such a challenge would be hard to objectively grade.

Comment: You could make it [tag:restricted-complexity] to prohibit brute force solutions

Answer (score 0):

## [Is it a plausible chess move](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/is-it-a-plausible-chess-move)

Comment: I would phrase this as "Can any piece move in this way", not "Under any arrangement of pieces ..." because there's never a reason to have more than one piece on the board.

Comment: Also, this should say "You need to know how the queen and knight move" - the rook is subsumed by the queen, as you point out. Also, you should mention that castling is ignored.

Comment: @isaacg clarified and simplified. I thought I had removed the rook move part from that sentence but I guess I hadn't :p

Answer (score 0):

## What is the shortest python code which implements a string-to-float function?

---

## Goal

Write the shortest variadic `to_float`, `str2float`, or standardizing function you can write subject to the constraint that the code is written in **python**.

---

## Rules and Examples

The variadic `str2float` shall be some callable which accepts any one of the following inputs:

| Input Data-type | Example Input | Output float |
| --- | --- | --- |
| string | `"4.992"` | float `4.992` |
| float s | `4.992` | float `4.992` |
| int | `9021` | float `9021.0` |
| a shallow iterable of strings | `["4", ".", "9", "9", "2"]` | float `4.992` |
| a string with zeros padded on the right and/or white-space padding on left | `"1234.650000\n"` | float `1234.65` |
| a string with zeros padded on the left | `"016"` | float `16.0` |
| a deeply nested iterable of strigs | `[["4", [[".", "9"]], ("9", "2")], ((((("1")), "0"), "1"), "0")]` | float `4.992101` |
| a deeply nested iterable of a mix of floats, int, and strings | `[[4.0, [[".", 9]], (9, "2")], (((("1")), "0"), "10")]` | float `4.992101` |

The main assumptions about the variadic `*args` parameter are that there is a correctly-working method named `__iter__` defined and that if you recursively search until `isinstance(obj, str)` returns `True` or `not hasattr('__iter__', obj)`, then the object which is not a string has a `__repr__` method which returns a string representation of a decimal point, integer, or floating point number.

## Scoring

The scoring will be something in between code-golf and popularity contest:

Score = `(upvotes - downvotes) - floor((bytes in code that outputs question) / 3)`

The highest score wins.

(You can use http://mothereff.in/byte-counter as a byte counter.)

Comment: It's not recommended to have popularity-contests any more. Also, it's not recommended to restrict the challenge to one language

Answer (score 0):

## I'm Lost!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening)

---

[Lost](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lost) is a 2d esolang where the instruction pointer starts at a random location. In this challenge, we'll replicate that for every language.

Your task is to write a program, which can be shifted any number of characters (these will be moved from the start to the end), and will still work. The program should print the string `Which way is` , followed any consistent string of your choice which is at least four characters, and a question mark.

**Example:**

Say my program is:

```
import print

print("Which way is Boston?")
```

What actually gets run might be:

```
port print

print("Which way is Boston?")im
```

(assuming there's no trailing newline)

Or:

```
print("Which way is Boston?")import print
```

Or:

```
ay is Boston?")import print

print("Which w
```

All of these must print the same, correct string.

**Sandbox:** I'm considering making the challenge to print how many characters your program was shifted by, but I'm worried that'd be impossible

Comment: Maybe you can add to the score the number of shifts that are impossible? That would allow languages to compete where this would otherwise be impossible

Comment: @mousetail Yeah, true. Ooh, what if I went with the print-the-amount-shifted-by thing, and factored the number of shift positions where it doesn't work into the score?

Comment: Your challenge may be inspired by Lost, but the shifting of the entire program in this challenge has nothing to do with the random starting position & direction of a Lost program.. The "_In this challenge, we'll replicate that for every language._" is basically false. Maybe change that sentence to something along the lines of "_Making a Lost program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky. In this challenge, we'll do something similar by having the same output for each rotation of your program, written in any language._"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well I mean, since most programming languages go from beginning to end, shifting it randomly does kinda emulate the random starting position. I do see what you mean tho, and I'll change that if I come back to this challenge at some point.

Answer (score 0):

## Compute Pi using pure arithmetic [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)[pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi)

This is a sequel to the challenge *[Primality testing formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170398/primality-testing-formula)*.

Given a positive integer \$ n \$ as input, write a **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)** function or program that outputs the first \$ n \$ digits of Pi as an \$ n \$-digit decimal integer using **pure arithmetic**. This means that your source code can only contain:

- operators `=, +, -, *, **, //, %, <<, >>, &, |, ^, ~, <, >, <=, >=, ==, !=`
- variables
- integer constants
- parentheses `()`
- semi-colons/newlines (to separate statements)

Unlike with the other challenge, you *may* use `=` if it helps speed up or simplify your code. However you may not use loops, built-ins, or anything else that's not stated above. Yes, it's possible.

#### Scoring

The winning criterion for this challenge is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code). You will be scored on the highest \$ n = 10^b \$ your code can compute in one minute. The time taken for that run will be used to break ties.

Hardcoding to prioritize certain test cases is not allowed, and the code must work in theory for all positive values of \$ n \$.

#### Test Cases

```
  n | output
----+--------
  1 | 3
 10 | 3141592653
100 | 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a fairly innocuous definition of a polygon:

> A polygon is a set of points \$P\$ in Euclidean space and set of edges each having two distinct endpoints in \$P\$, such that the edges form a single cycle.

We will define a *regular* polygon then as:

> Take each edge of the polygon and divide it into two halves of equal length. The polygon is **regular** if for any pair of half edges, \$A\$ and \$B\$, there is an isometry of ambient space that maps every half edge to another and maps \$A\$ to \$B\$.

This can informally be phrased as "no two edges or faces are distinguishable by anything other than absolute position". You may also hear the common phrasing "all edges are the same length and all angles are equal".

Now the astute among you will be quick to point out that while this allows for what we normally consider polygons it also includes so called "star-polygons" such as the pentagram:

[image: A pentagram!]

These edges intersect each other, but we didn't forbid this. So by the definition this is a valid 5-sided polygon.

These sort of edge cases are sort of common knowledge. However the even more astute among you may have noticed a much stranger loophole.  I said "Euclidean space", not "*2-dimensional* Euclidean space".

## Skew polygons

So can we make new polygons in higher dimensional spaces? Yes, for example here's a regular 6-sided polygon in 3D space:

[image: Skew hexagon]
*Image curteousy of Polytope wiki user Sycamore916, CC-BY-SA-4.0*

It turns out for example we can take any even sided polygon and raise half of its vertices up out of the plane to get a "skew" version of it that is 3D. And in 4D we can do even stranger things.

### Challenge statement

The challenge is going to be to count these skew polygons. You are going to take an integer > 2 and output a list \$a\$ where \$a_d\$ represents the number of distinct regular polygons in \$d\$ dimensions.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Definitions

In order for this to work we must add 2 more definitions, the first is what makes two polygons distinct and the second is the dimension of a polygon.

> A polygon in \$d\$ dimensions is a polygon such that the affine span of its vertices is a \$d\$-dimensional subspace.

For example the following vertices form a triangle:

$$
(1,0,0)\\
(0,1,0)\\
(0,0,1)
$$

Each coordinate is given in 3D, however the polygon itself is 2D since all of its vertices lie on the same plane.

> Two polygons \$A\$ and \$B\$ are **the same** if there is an invertible linear transform taking \$A\$ to \$B\$. Two polygons are **distinct** if they are not the same.

For example the skew hexagon discussed earlier can be stretched vertically by any positive factor. These do not count as distinct polygons since stretching is an invertible linear transform. However the skew hexagon is *distinct* from the normal planar hexagon since the stretch factor would be 0, and that linear transformation is not invertable (you cannot divide by 0).

Very nicely these two definitions coincide so that if two polygons have different dimensions they are automatically distinct, so there is no ambiguity as to how to count them.

### Test cases

```
3 -> [0,1]
4 -> [0,1,1]
5 -> [0,2,0,1]
6 -> [0,1,2,1,1]
7 -> [0,3,0,3,0,1]
8 -> [0,2,2,3,3,1,1]
9 -> [0,3,0,6,0,4,0,1]
```

### Spoilers

Here's the part where I would explain where the magic numbers come from.

Comment: Your 6-sided polygon looks like a Cyclohexane...

Answer (score 0):

## Monopoly, But its in Creative Mode (sort of) [koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth)

## Disjointed Monopoly (?)

Starting Grid: 8x8 grid:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|XX|  |  |  |  |  |  |XX|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |+1|  |  |  |  |+1|  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |+2|+1|+1|+2|  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |+1|x2|x2|+1|  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |+1|x2|x2|+1|  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |+2|+1|+1|+2|  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |+1|  |  |  |  |+1|  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|XX|  |  |  |  |  |  |XX|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

For each group of four players (grouped randomly),
we run the game above with the four players starting
at the `+1` squares near the corner with 20 dollars each.

To ensure that no player is left over, each entry will
be run four times. It is possible that two or more will
compete against each other, but the grouping is random.
(The order is also random.)

#### Objective: Eliminate all other players.

All players that has to pay more money than they can are eliminated.

(For all random numbers / choices, assume equal probability.)

We choose a random position and a random number of steps
1 ~ 4, and the bot moves in that directions. The map wraps
around. Then, if the bot steps on...

- a Player: That player is eliminated instantly,
  and you do not execute the current square action.
- someone else's Property: Pay that someone the ammount
  equal to `2^rank` dollars. `rank` is the rank of the
  property.
- your own Property: Choose whether to upgrade the
  property rank by 1 costing you `2*2^rank` dollars.
  `rank` is the **current** rank of the property.
- any Utility station: get `2*rank` dollars, and
  the utility station automatically upgrades its
  rank by 1.
- corner of Board (XX): Lose 20% of your money,
  rounded down.
- otherwise: Do an Action.

When you step on an empty cell (a cell not qualifying any of the above),
you can do an Action. You can either:

- Build your own Property: Use 10 dollars to build a
  Property right here with a random integer rank between 1 and 4.
- Build your own Utility: Use 2 dollars to build a
  Utility station right here with a random integer rank between 1 and 4.
- Demolish a Square's structure. This will not demolish the bonus on the
  structure (for instance `*2` and `+1`) and can apply to `XX` squares.
  This action has 25% probability of successing.

#### Demolish cost (paid even if failed):

- Property: `2*rank` dollars. (Even if it is yours.)
- Utility: `rank` dollars.
- Other (including `XX`): no cost.

#### Bonus

Squares marked with `+1`, `+2`, and `*2` have added bonus.
The operations are applied to the rank when a structure is built on
the square the bonus occupies. For instance, if a ranked 3
Utility is built on a `*2` square, it will start at rank 6 instead.
Everything else proceeds normally.

### Meta: Gimme a better name for the challenge

Comment: Better name: **Disjointed Monopoly**

Comment: I think something's wrong with the title that says **Objective**

Comment: What does "disjointed" have to do with this?

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian fixed

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms hence searching for better name

Answer (score 0):

## Trippples

### Introduction

[Tripples (BGG)](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2040/trippples) is a board game from the 1970s.

It is played on an 8x8 grid, and each tile on that grid (except the corner starting tiles, and four blank tiles) contain three arrows. The three arrows each point in one of eight directions (up, down, left, right; and diagonally between those). There are therefore 56 tiles, and 56 unique combinations of arrows - so each tile is unique when placed in the correct orientation.

Tiles are placed on the board, and depending on the variant of the rules being played this can either happen before the game starts (face up, either randomly or players take turns to draw and place tiles as they choose), before the game starts (face down, randomly), or over the course of the game as an alternative player action, instead of moving their playing piece.

Players start in adjacent corners and attempt to cross the board to the diagonally-opposite corner before their opponents can do so.

Players take turns, and may move their playing piece one square per turn. **The interesting thing about this game is that the direction they can move is limited to the directions indicated by the arrows underneath their *opponent's* playing piece.**

The rules are ambivalent regarding how the blank pieces are treated - either you can't go there at all, you get a second move if you can go there, or (house rule) your opponent can choose to move in any direction if you land there.

### The challenge

*(sandbox note: I discovered this game recently and thought it could be the basis for an interesting challenge - what the challenge is, though, I'm flexible on; so I'm happy to take suggestions. What is below is just one idea)*

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

Competitors write bots to play against another bot, in a Trippples competition.

*(sandbox query: which variant of the game rules is most interesting?)

A server program will provide the board state, and the competitor bot's function should return its next move.

Comment: Linked to [the puzzling SE question you made.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/120984/78946)

Answer (score 0):

## Longest Tiles Combo

The New York Times has a puzzle game called  [Tiles](https://www.nytimes.com/puzzles/tiles) on their website. This game consists of a grid of tiles, each made of multiple visual elements which are shared between tiles.  The player first selects two tiles which share any visual element, removing those tiles from play. If the player then selects a third tile which matches some visual element with the second, their combo increases; they can repeat this process multiple times to increase their combo.

For example, take the following row:

[image]

The player could begin by selecting the middle and left tiles, which share the black middle square; they then could select the right tile, because the left and right tile share a purple square and a light blue background.

---

In this challenge, the grid of tiles will be represented by a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the same number of symbols; each symbol represents a visual element on the tile. For example, the above could be encoded as

```
[("light blue BG", "purple square", "small black square"), 
 ("orange BG", "purple circle", "small black square"),
 ("light blue BG", "purple square", "small black diamond")]
```

Note that for all of the tuples, the elements will be described in the same order -- e.g. the background will always be the first item in the tuple.

You can decide the set of symbols which are used; in the examples below, I'll use integers instead of strings, e.g.

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 3), (1, 2, 6)]
```

The input format is flexible; for example, since order doesn't matter, you could use a set instead of a list, and instead of tuples you could use lists, strings, or sets.

Given the input as above, your goal is to output an integer indicating the ***largest possible combo length possible***. You can assume there will be at least one matching pair of tiles -- i.e. the max combo will be at least one.

### Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `[(0), (0)]` | `1` |
| `[(0), (0), (1)]` | `1` |
| `[(2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)]` | `2` |
| `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 3), (1, 2, 6)]` | `2` |
| `[(9, 1, 14), (9, 17, 5), (3, 10, 14), (0, 13, 11), (16, 13, 6)]` | `2` |
| `[(4, 3, 1), (8, 0, 2), (7, 6, 2), (8, 6, 5), (4, 6, 2)]` | `4` |
| `[(16, 8), (12, 8), (15, 17), (18, 5), (12, 6), (0, 5)]` | `2` |
| `[(5, 1), (2, 9), (3, 15), (11, 0), (5, 9), (2, 14)]` | `3` |

[Here's some very inefficient code to generate your own test cases.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVPLTsMwEDxw85UfWLWXmKYVjwuq1DMXQNytKEobp7WU2JbtoPZbuPQCH8XXsF4nLUglUh7e2Z2dndgfX_YQdkYfj599aOaP31fXqrPGBXCVrk3HmO67Uray87CCe1r5UAXpSysdARh_oHhQrfS0YvGz9DLgqlU-ZEi2ldml4hs4NeCcpaYLv-ubppXZSMMZm8KT1NJhMaxN5WpGT-QXobeYKhjgNRaIgSi-lA7ZbX6h9_yOwwz-UaV4QYwAjXGgQGk4D5HkFpyw8i9GLmCxdbExqST5b87U_UaC6YPtA8LyvdyYbm18DumNw7waLXMQQhWX2o7UEaKSCKfaJYkl0piFVNRZECrmd0WahkjrfU5GxWqJvOTqoHQ5DA2gGsgwFbQJpzYc0E-8Dxm5hGHiiaxj4CThF1W8ksxFZa3UdZbUz0Bgh4KzaTKrlTohcSt01b7EAE6CXxntoq6yMWf0i2NWKpy8VPvBEcS3Ybec5DAQ4F8es54NOunDaBnmiA2J35yNjHOTDr5aDQwFT2djOCLjUfkB)

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

Answer (score 0):

## What is possible with all these blocks?

In this challenge, you will write code (in any way) that outputs the number of permutations of all sub-tuples of a tuple of length \$n\$ (also [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522)(n) ). Here’s an example:

> You have three blocks. You can start by counting how many arrangements of three blocks are possible (6). Then, work out how many ways there are to arrange two blocks (2) and multiply that by the number of unique pairs of blocks you can pick from the three blocks (3) to get the sub-answer (6). Then, work out how many ways you can arrange 1 object (1) and multiply that by the number of unique blocks you can pick from the three blocks (3) to get the sub-answer (3). Then, remember the number of empty combinations (1). Add those together to get the answer (16).

This is code golf, so shortest answer wins!

Comment: This is [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522)

Comment: @CommandMaster i forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 0):

## [Landmine Number V](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262794/landmine-number-v)

Answer (score 0):

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63012181#63012181

Make a 0-byte metagolfscript solution that outputs its name.

Shortest name wins.

Comment: I feel like this will be closed as a duplicate of the output your program’s name challenge.

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev No. In that question metagolfscript is banned due to standard loophole. In this only metagolfscript allowed

Comment: This still seems like an underspecified challenge for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Compute 0.1+0.2+0.3+...+0.8+0.9+0.10+0.11+0.12+...+0.[n]

Test cases

```
10  -> 4.6
25  -> 7.3
64  -> 24.85
256 -> 81.496
```

## Sandbox Note

Dupscanner

Comment: What will the maximum n be, and what kind of precision are you looking for?

Comment: @Adám Accuracy shouldn't be a problem if only 5 significant digits when n=256

Comment: The number of significant digits is of course ⌊log *n*⌋ which means hitting 64-bit float issues when n approaches 10¹⁷.

Answer (score 0):

## JSON Data? ASCII is better!

Write a function that prints JSON data using [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), and takes a dictionary/object as input.

Example

```
Input:
{
    "columns": ["firstname", "lastname"],
    "data": [
        {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"},
        {"firstname": "Jack", "lastname": "Barrock"},
        {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Skeet"},
        ....
    ]
}

Output:

+---------------------------+
|  firstname  |  lastname   |
+---------------------------+
|     John    |     Doe     |
|     Jack    |   Barrock   |
| ...                       |
+---------------------------+
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes win.

**Note:** The input will always have a column attribute, and will always have a data attribute. Think of it as SQL.

Comment: Thanks for posting here. Some feedback:
1. Challenge should be fully specified before the test cases. Specifically, how the table is drawn, centered text, what characters are used for table formatting etc.
2. You need more test cases. At least 5 if you can cover all edge cases that way

Comment: I'm not sure if you fix those that it would be sufficienly different from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69560/58563) Arnould mentioned. Note challenges don't need to be identical to be duplicates, closely related challenges can also be closed if they have the same general structure for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Separate two points in a topological space](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263926/find-separating-sets)

Answer (score 0):

## [Is it a valid Go type?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263827/77309)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[syntax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Answer (score 0):

## [Compressed UTF-8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264140/compressed-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

## 2D Percolation Model

Per Wolfram MathWorld: "Percolation theory deals with fluid flow (or any other similar process) in random media."

The model is a 2 dimensional lattice whose edges are either "open" or "closed" with probability p in [0,1]. At a percolation probability P, each edge will be evaluated to be open or closed based on if P>p. Connected vertices compose a "cluster". For display purposes, clusters are often colored or otherwise uniquely denoted. An example of a percolation model is shown below:

**3x3 Lattice**

```
       Lattice                 Lattice with random 
                                edge values shown

 o ------ o ------ o           o -0.12- o -0.99- o
 |        |        |           |        |        |
 |        |        |          0.75     0.09     0.52
 |        |        |           |        |        |
 o ------ o ------ o           o -0.46- o -0.23- o
 |        |        |           |        |        |
 |        |        |          0.39     0.12     0.85
 |        |        |           |        |        |
 o ------ o ------ o           o -0.97- o -0.23- o
```

**Percolation at P = 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9 yields 4 clusters**

```
       P = 0.1                    P = 0.5                   P = 0.9

 o ------ o ------ o        o        o ------ o        o        o ------ o
 |                 |        |                 |                           
 |                 |        |                 |                             
 |                 |        |                 |                           
 o ------ o ------ o        o        o        o        o        o        o
 |        |        |                          |                        
 |        |        |                          |                        
 |        |        |                          |                        
 o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o        o ------ o        o
```

**Vertices named according to cluster**

```
P = 0.1                      P = 0.5                    P = 0.9

A A A                        A B B                      A B B
A A A                        A C B                      C D E
A A A                        D D B                      F F G
```

## Challenge

Given a side length n and percolation probability P, create a percolation model of lattice size n x n with vertices displayed according to the cluster they belong to. The shortest code wins!

## Inputs

The model shall take two inputs: n, P

1. n is the side length of the lattice
2. P is the percolation probability

## Output

The model shall return an n x n display of vertices. Its a model so readability is important! List of lists, arrays, or pretty printing is allowed so long as there are n rows and n columns. Vertices shall have alphanumeric names of the same length to ensure readability. Edges need not be shown.

## Rules

1. Cluster names shall be unique
2. The model shall be able to compute any percolation phase state from P = 0 to P = 1

Answer (score 0):

## Worst algorithm for anything

Now, any coder worth their salt will know how to sort an array in-place in `nlogn`time. Most can probably figure out a way to do it in `n!n` time and factorial memory usage. Let's see an algorithm that tops those numbers; can you come up with a way to sort an array in up-arrow time? Can you come up with an algorithm whose O-notation contains the [Graham's number series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)?

### Rules:

- The algorithm must solve a problem that isn't just an obfuscation of 'do a ridiculous amount of NOPs".
- Highest O-notation in either memory usage or time wins, tie broken by the other one and then by a golfed implementation.

### Discussion

I'm not sure whether I should limit this to solving a specific problem. For that matter, I don't know if this would be an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

### Periodicity of the family of sequences s(n) such that n(x) is the first number co-prime with the previous `n` elements [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The sequence of all numbers coprime to the previous is all natural numbers. This is [OEIS 000027](https://oeis.org/A000027):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
```

The sequence starting with 1, 2, and where the n-th term is the first number coprime to the previous 2 in the sequence, is periodic with period 6 (2x3). This is [OEIS 047255](https://oeis.org/A047255)

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23
```

If you take the first number coprime with the previous 3 terms, you get a sequence periodic with a period of 210 (2*3*5*7). This is [OEIS 062062](https://oeis.org/A062062)

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43
```

Your task is, given a number N output the periodicity of the co-prime sequence taking the last N terms.

As stated, the first elements of this sequence are:

```
1, 6, 210
```

The fourth is unknown, yet your program, given enough time, should in theory calculate it. It is known to be at least 245,589. It should not be extremely hard to calculate, just nobody has tried yet.

MathJax test, please ignore: \$abc\$

Comment: Probably worth showing at least one example of n(x) for clarity's sake

Answer (score 0):

## Complex logarithm

*We have challenges for the regular [real logarithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262711/vanilla-natural-logarithm-challenge) and the [matrix logarithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263530/compute-the-logarithm-of-a-matrix), but we do not yet have a challenge for computing the logarithm of a complex number.*

...

I will add a challenge body if there is interest

...

### Rules

- You may chose which logarithm of the import you return as long as the imaginary parts for any two returned values differ by at most \$2\pi\$
- Please add built-in solutions to the community-Wiki post
- ... *More rules will follow*
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution in bytes wins

### Meta

- Is this different enough from the other two challenges ?

  As far as I can tell most (no built-in) algorithms used in these challenges break when applied to complex inputs
- Would there be interest in solving this challenge ?

Comment: Isn't the complex logarithm not unique? Which value(s) should answers output?

Comment: To bsoelch: I find this challenge boring (I’ll abstain from voting because it isn’t terrible either).

@Bbrk24 The term is _principal_ natural logarithm. Real part ≔ ln | x |; and imaginary part ≔ arg(x) ∩ (−π, +π] in radians.

Answer (score 0):

## When is My Holiday?

### Background

I recently learned of a holiday, that occurred on August 20, 2023 and August 12, 2022.
This got me wondering how on earth they were determining which day this holiday falls on.

### The Challenge

In this challenge you will be given two dates which are from the same month but different years as input. You must construct the simplest possible description which applies to both dates.

Descriptions must be structured in a particular way. First, there are types of days

| type | cost |
| --- | --- |
| day | 1 |
| Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday | 1 |
| weekday, weekend day | 1 |
| day which is a multiple of \$N\$ | \$N\$ |

For the following we'll let \$D\$ be some type of day. We then have modifiers and constants.

| modifier | constant |
| --- | --- |
| the nth \$D\$ after | the nth \$D\$ |
| the nth \$D\$ before | the nth to last \$D\$ |
| the nearest \$D\$ to |  |

A valid description consists of 0 or more modifiers followed by a single constant. The simplest description is the one with the lowest cost, which is the sum of the cost of each \$D\$ which appears in the description.

For the purposes of this challenge we define "nearest" to mean "nearer than all others" so if there is a tie, then neither day is nearest and the description is not valid. "Nearest" may include the day itself. "Before" and "after" do not include the day itself.

### I/O

Standard I/O rules apply, the dates may be taken in any reasonable format. And since the challenge is not about supposed to be about date calculation you may choose to take in data about the month surrounding each day. Some examples of valid input formatting are as follows. A program would take two such inputs.

```
2023-08-22

8/22/23

22.8.23

[[xx, xx, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05]
 [06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12]
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
 [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, xx, xx]], 
[3, 2]
```

You may assume any input given will have a solution. Your description need not apply to all years, just the ones in the input (eg. August 2023 has no 5th monday, but "the 5th monday" is still correct for 2021-08-30, 2022-08-29). If two or more descriptions tie you may output any or all.

Output the elements as seen in the tables above separated by spaces.

### Test Cases

These test cases follow the `YYYY-MM-DD` input format

```
2022-07-04, 2023-07-04 -> the 4th day
2021-08-30, 2022-08-29 -> the 5th monday
2022-08-12, 2023-08-20 -> the 1st day which is a multiple of 4 before the 3rd Monday
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)

---

How clear is this?

Should I be more lenient on output? (allow encoding schemes)

Yes I'm going to add more test cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate equal, winning or losing trades in chess

*For this challenge, assume you are playing white*

---

Given two arrays containing all white and black chess piece positions on a chessboard, output if a given square is a **equal**, **losing** or **winning** trade. If there is no trade for a giving square, output something else.

- An **equal trade** happens when both black and white can lose the same amount of material in a given square
- A **winning trade** happens when white loses less material than black in a given square.
- A **losing trade** happens when white loses more material than black in a given square.

---

**Example**

```
Input: 
Black -> ["Ra8", "Bc8", "Qd8", "Rf8", "Kg8", "Nd7", "Ne7", "Bg7", "a6", "b5", ...
White -> ["Rd1", "Rf1", ...
Target -> "d5"

Output: Equal Trade
```

*Visually would be:*

[image]

---

**Meta**

- Would this be interesting?
- I'm not sure If I should allowed dynamic calculations or no. For example in the previous image, for square f5, there would be an equal trade since pawn attacks f5 square and if it takes, bishop will now be able to attack f5 square

---

*I will add more examples later...*

Answer (score 0):

## BB⁻¹(TREE(3))

Construct a Turing machine with tape alphabet {0, 1} that, starting on a tape filled with 0, it halts with at least TREE(3) 1's. Least states wins.

## Notes

As [math scat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/math-scat) mentioned, this [is asked in math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929521/when-does-busy-beaver-surpass-tree3), but such a question may fit better here LOL

Answer (score 0):

## Return every possible program with positive probability

Write a program or function a (subset of a) Program language of your choice that returns every possible Program **in the same Language** with a positive probability

### Rules

- You are allowed to take a stream of random bits as input
- Each program in your language has to have a positive probability to appear
- All returned programs have to be syntactically correct *(META: might need further clarification)*
- If in your language every string satisfies the above condition, consider using a different language

### [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

### Meta

- Would this be an interesting challenge/ is this a duplicate?
- Should I add minimum language requirements (Turing completeness...)?
- Is "syntactically correct" clear
- Possible variant with more clear definition: 
  *"Generate every python program"*

Comment: Regarding whether "syntactically correct" is clear, I'm not sure. In standard languages it's fairly clear - its compilation doesn't terminate with a syntax error (although even that might be vague if the compilation can halt earlier due to another, valid, factor). But in a lot of esolangs every finite string of characters is a well formed program, so it might give them a very very significant advantage. You should also specify whether the language your code is in must be the same as the one it outputs.

Comment: This seems like it would be incredibly difficult for any language with moderately complicated syntax (e.g. Python), so limiting it to a language like that wouldn't likely result in any valid answers IMO

Answer (score 0):

## Simulate Feedback Scheduling on a Uniprocessor

*Alternatively, exploiting university course content for code golf reputation*

Like [round robin scheduling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265060/simulate-round-robin-scheduling), Feedback Scheduling is a way to schedule ready processes in an operating system. And like round robin scheduling, it runs processes for a certain amount of time (quantum), interrupted after that time (if not yet finished), and then added back to a ready queue for another round.

However, the key difference is that as a process repeatedly goes through the ready queue, it gets a longer quantum<sup>1</sup>. This can be compared to having multiple ready queues and processors daisy-chained as so:

[image]

In the diagram, the first ready queue sends its processes to the first process to run for some time \$k\$. If the process finishes in this time, it is released. Otherwise, it is sent to the second ready queue, which has a quantum of \$2k\$.<sup>2</sup> The second ready queue sends its processes to the second processor to run for some time \$2k\$. Once again, if the process finishes in this time, the process is released. Otherwise, it is sent to the third ready queue. This generalises all the way down to the nth ready queue, which has interrupted processes sent back to itself. That is, it gets readded to the nth ready queue in a loop.

As this is a uniprocessor simulation, there's only one processor, so the concept of daisy-chaining multiple processors doesn't really work<sup>3</sup>. However, this can be simulated by using process priorities. Indeed, a higher priority process would be in one of the higher ready queues (closer to the first ready queue).  A lower priority process would be in one of the lower ready queues (closer to the nth ready queue). A process with priority \$n\$ will be executed for \$n k\$, where \$k\$ is the quantum.

The priority only changes how long a process is executed. It does not change the selection order of the ready queue - that's still a first-come first-serve selection method. Processes arrive with a priority of `1`, so as to not have any processes running for 0 time units.

### The Challenge

Given a list of `[int, int]` (both > 0), as well as a base quantum, and a maximum priority, return a list of `int` representing the order that processes were executed. Assume that all the processes arrive at the same time.

The list of `[int, int]` represents a (simplified) list of processes. The two ints are the process id and service time (the time the process needs to fully run). (The priority is to be handled by the program, as all processes start with priority 1).

For example:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 10], [3, 3], [4, 12]]
```

Represents the following processes

| Process ID | Service Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 12 |

The base quantum is how long each priority runs, before priority multiplication. The maximum priority represents the priority at which processes loop back into the same quantum.

### Worked Example

Using the above process list (`[[1, 5], [2, 10], [3, 3], [4, 12]]`), a quantum of `4`, and a maximum priority of `4`, the process execution order will be:

```
TODO: Worked example at a time that isn't 11:39pm
```

### Rules

- Input can be taken as `list[list[int, int]], int, int`, `list[int], list[int], int, int`, or some other reasonable input method.
- The processes, quantum and maximum priority can be taken in any order.
- For example:

```
list[int: processIds]
list[int: serviceTimes]
int: quantum
int: maximumPriority
```

or

```
int: maximumPriority
list[int: serviceTimes]
int: quantum
list[int: processIds]
```

or any other combination.

- Output can be `list[int]`, `str` (joined on newlines, or spaces, or any constant delimiter) or some other reasonable output method.
- There will always be at least one process.
- The process ids list will always be a permutation of the range `[1, number of processes]`.
- The process ids can be 0-indexed if you want it to be for some reason. Using 0-indexing, the ids list will always be a permutation of the range `[0, number of processes]`.
- The order of the process ids list is important - processes are executed in the order they arrive (in a first come first serve manner). That is how the ready queue in an actual FB simulation works after all (FCFS selection strategy, with pre-emption on time quantums).

### Test Cases

```
TODO: Write
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

### Sandbox Meta

- Does the description I've provided make sense? It's not verbatim how FB scheduling works, but it's a simplification to make code golfing it not as tedious as it could be.
- Because I don't have a worked example/test cases yet, some parts might not make sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some variants of Feedback Scheduling use constant time slices for all quantums. However, this challenge will assume a variable time quantum, so as to provide fairness to longer processes.

<sup>2</sup> The factor of 2 is arbitrary. It could be any integer > 1.

<sup>3</sup> At least, not with the simplification provided for this challenge. In practice, it might still work.

Answer (score 0):

## Digits of Infinity (computing A206636) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

In [this PDF](https://www.vixra.org/pdf/2111.0004v1.pdf), https://www.vixra.org outlines a way to find the last \$ n \$<sup>1, 3</sup> digits of infinity and a method to do so.

Let us define the *infinity sequence*<sup>2</sup>, taking the function \$ f(n) \$.

\$ f(1) = 2^2 = 4\$
\$ f(n) = 2^{f(n-1)}\$

Starting from \$ f(3) \$, the last \$ n - 2 \$ digits are the same for all \$ f(n) \$ numbers with \$ n \gt 2 \$ in this sequence.

Your task: given an integer \$ n \$ through standard I/O, return the last \$ n \$ digits of infinity.

### Input

`n`, an integer (or the closest to one in your language), \$ \ge 1 \$ (if 1-indexed; you can also take a zero-indexed input, but the number of digits outputted will then have to be `n+1`). Most programs will probably compute \$ f(n+2) \$ for the output, which is permissible (but not compulsory; I'd love to see any other creative way for large `n`, though no bonus points). Input will be less than or equal to the highest number `n` such that your program can compute in under 2 minutes.

### Output

The last `n` (or `n+1` if 0-indexed) digits of infinity (through accepted I/O).

### Test Cases:

```
Input -> Output

1 -> 6
2 -> 36
3 -> 736
10 -> 3432948736
22 -> 8098615075353432948736
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

Note: my bet is that most programs that are well-golfed will not be able to calculate these digits easily; \$ f(5) \$ has over 19000 digits! However, if your program, given infinite time, infinite memory, and unbounded integer types, can compute this, it's valid.

<sup>1. Apparently, the digits of infinity are infinite.
2. This is OEIS A206636.
3. I do not believe in this method, I just picked it out because I thought it would make for a good challenge.</sup>

Comment: Infinity is not a number. Therefore, it cannot have digits. The paper seems a bit sketchy to my knowledge of different infinities.

Comment: [What are the differences between viXra.org and arXiv.org?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/105518) "Warranted or not, it has a reputation of being an alternative to arXiv for cranks and to host a lot of junk science, fake proofs or even outright nonsense"

Comment: I would suggest it be named differently, like "A206636". This removes the dependency on viXtra. I also agree with the above, infinity is a concept, not a number, unless they are talking about p-adics, although that's unlikely.

Comment: I'd upvote because this would be a challenge that really punishes naive approaches, due to the tetrative growth. Also, is there a limit on the inputs? Because `-1` is also an integer, and so is `2^127-1`

Comment: This paper shows such a violent misunderstanding of infinity it's comical.

Comment: Alright, everyone; I don't *actually* believe that the digits of infinity can be calculated with such a simple sequence; I just chose this because I just thought the sequence was an interesting one. And yes, there is a limit; only from `1` may the inputs be passed.

Comment: I my opinion allowing solutions that compute `f(n+2)` and then take the last `n` digits, makes the challenge less interesting. I would suggest some requirement for reasonable running time (e.g. "the program has to be able to compute the result for `n=10` in less than a minute on a modern computer").

Comment: Would it be allowed that the program only works up to n=18 (largest result that fits in a signed 64-bit integer), or do you require big-int support

Comment: @bsoelch about your earlier comment; it's a mistake with my framing: I meant that most trivial programs will do this, and it's not compulsory (that would be a non-observable requirement), and the second comment, I believe my last part makes the ruling on that clear (if your code \*practically\* can compute up till `n=18`, and theoretically can compute for any `n`, then it's valid)

Comment: If infinity did indeed have digits, it would have to be an infinite stream of 0s, since it has to be a multiple of every power of 10.

Comment: False; I could make a bigger infinity by adding 1.

Comment: @UndoneStudios but that can’t be an infinity, because it is not divisible by 10. Infinity must be an “integer” multiple of every single number.

Comment: You are assuming a value of infinity as a value; it is not; but the point is it cannot be an infinite stream, because that would make it indivisible by... it's a complicated topic, and that's the reason why we don't consider \*infinity\* to be a value, which I already explained in my earlier comment. Also, such a definition would be recursive and would include itself as well, causing issues in calculation.

Comment: Your definition is one of multiple definitions, but it is absolutely not the definition I hold when thinking of infinity as having digits.

Answer (score 0):

## Roll a ball down an array

You are in a frictionless environment in a vacuum. [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/669/)

You are given a inertialess, sizeless point mass which you have to roll down a slope. The ball starts with 0 speed.

If a ball has 0 speed and is touching the ground, it gains 1 speed in the direction of the lowest adjacent point. If both adjacent heights are the same, add 1 speed in the direction last traveled.
When a ball **changes direction, subtract 1 speed** after the change. (This ensures that no loops occur)

The ball gains or loses speed based on the difference between the ball's current height, and the end height. A ball moves to the lowest possible square where the speed obeys the formula.
$$(speed+1)^2 < (h-newh)^2 + (idx-newidx)^2$$

Given an array of integer heights, return the steps for the ball to settle/escape.

### Ball Speed-move diagram

```
     . 4 4 4 .
   4 4 3 3 3 4 4
 . 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 . 
 4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4
 4 3 2 1 O 1 2 3 4
 4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4
 . 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 .
   4 4 3 3 3 4 4
     . 4 4 4 .
```

## Examples:

```
[5,3,2,1,2,4] -> 5


Diagram:     Ball SPD = 1 Ball SPD = 2 Ball SPD = 3 BALL SPD = 1 Ball ESCAPED!
0            1            2            3            4            5
()           x\
55           55()         55 x         55           55        () 55         x
55        44 55        44 55()      44 55 x`\,   44 55        44 55        44
5533      44 5533      44 5533      44 5533  ()  44 5533   x  44 5533      44
553322  2244 553322  2244 553322  2244 553322  2244 553322  2244 553322  2244
553322112244 553322112244 553322112244 553322112244 553322112244 553322112244

 0 1   2   3     4
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] -> 5

          SPEED 1   SPEED 2   SPEED 4   SPEED 7   BALL ESCAPED
0         1         2         3         4         5
@         x
9         9@        9x        9         9         9         
98        98        98 @      98 x      98        98        
987       987       987       987       987       987       
9876      9876      9876      9876 @    9876 x    9876      
98765     98765     98765     98765     98765     98765     
987654    987654    987654    987654    987654    987654    
9876543   9876543   9876543   9876543   9876543 @ 9876543 x 
98765432  98765432  98765432  98765432  98765432  98765432  
977654321 977654321 977654321 977654321 977654321 977654321

 0 1   2   3     4             5
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1] -> 6

 0 1 2
[2,1,2] -> 3

 0 1
   2
   0 (Loses 1 speed due to the direction change)

[2,1,3] -> 4
```

## Questions for sandbox:

- How many more test cases should I add?
- Are there any inconsistencies or rules that need clarification?

Answer (score 0):

really shitty sloppy wip but i just want to start this post so that i can be past the first hurdle next time i look at this. feel free to ask anything just know this is like step 0;

#### implement this weird algorithm which will be given a more descriptive name

here is the algorithm in js:

```js
f = x => x.reduce((a, b) => [b, ...f(a)], [])
```

implement this program in your language of choice;

#### rules

[restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) it has to run in faster time complexity than this naive implementation, which is like, exponential i think.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) shortest code wins

notes: i might make it so you only have to output the result of running this on range lists like [0 1 2 3 ... n], so only the permutation that the algorithm results in, rather than for arbitrary input, since generating the permutation is one thing and then applying it is another

Answer (score 0):

## Find an eigenvalue of a 3x3 Matrix

Write a program of function that given a 3x3 matrix as input outputs an Eigenvalue of that matrix

Examples/Test-cases:

```
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]    -> 1.0
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,7]]    -> -0.22165260583979401
[[5,3,4],[2,6,7],[0,4,10]]   -> 1.887934888738847
[[-3,2,5],[0,6,7],[0,0,-10]] -> -3.0
[[0.2915131378594483, 0.41257765061649787, 0.9253019986284902], [0.21696836678486353, 0.5331738150906348, 0.3247753676328128], [0.20672257620794932, 0.3453811902047663, 0.4771215769253173]] -> -0.03135020654472091
[[0.2447175622890705, 0.38693057299215594, 0.8576673327257548], [0.47607062999761074, 0.1126298515845301, 0.9707452917395663], [0.7524371727807047, 0.502675518344781, 0.6725321940186385]] -> -0.2768104753672565
```

### Rules

- You can take the matrix in any convenient format
- The input matrix will be 3x3, the entries will be in the interval `[-10,10]`
- The error of your result should be at most `10^-5`
- Your program may fail for some inputs as long as the probability of failure for a Matrix with uniformly distributed entries is 0
- You can choose any eigenvalue as output, and may return different values on different calls
- You are **not** allowed to use built-in functions that directly compute a eigenvalue/eigenvector of a matrix
- You are allowed to use other matrix functions but are encouraged to solve the problem without matrix built-ins

### Example solution in Python (non-golfed)

*Uses a derivative-free variation of Newtons algorithm on the determinant*

```python
def det(M):
  return (M[0][0]*M[1][1]*M[2][2]+M[0][1]*M[1][2]*M[2][0]+M[0][2]*M[1][0]*M[2][1]-
          M[2][0]*M[1][1]*M[0][2]-M[2][1]*M[1][2]*M[0][0]-M[2][2]*M[1][0]*M[0][1])

def copy(M):
  return [[a for a in R]for R in M]

def subtX(M,x):
  N=copy(M)
  for i in range(len(M)):
    N[i][i]-=x;
  return N

def eigenValue(M):
  x0=0;x1=1;y0=1
  while abs(y0)>1e-5:
    N0=subtX(M,x0)
    N1=subtX(M,x1)
    y0=det(N0);y1=det(N1)
    x0,x1=x0-y0*(x1-x0)/(y1-y0),x0
  return x0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVXLbhtHEESAnPQVeySdpdM9Pd09bYH5A-ngQxCA2ANtUzYBgRJoCiG_JRdfkv_JNZf8Smpml5YMhCYW2GFtdXX1Y8k__no8HT497L58-fPpcLco__zw74fNXfdhc5jdzN9cdd1-c3ja77rZzYoGXK9uVjzgwj0NuH5qOE94mnCa8DThNOE8LCB5_kzUF5ItZDFRX0i21Isp5QvJlnp-dVUtv394PH3rebVad3cP-27dbXfd26Ee39bjzTBGfH56d_htdtMfW9DtclLAuVK3lbpf7z5uZvebHfDGAm-1HXAtlsfr51S3o-Jm-3Gz-3V9_7SZnBxpSddHXvL1iZYM4PdP2_tNt373eXai-S-8WeikSsuvdmg-QvwM8QhBpE7mlubXJx6P05MjgbQ80uJEr2ZHXkDk59mJ8XUOwWejR5rm_OPfj_vt7jB7YXm14p56GvoV9TzdcRqG-fzqf8mpF5Byr73h7n3p_RJZe-kzSKk3kKpy7jldYi8E2tpoZzr1C75ohV6nYGVh8aKRc5G-o9eZk7qbkrHl8OIVjKRCHFEslRyUhr6r4WxhRcy85GKiLV5F2KWwUpBJLhWTlN1VzE1S4VSmcDJPSGaJPHJIatSsCGbkoOxmoyV3TgxitQHx7xSUs7OrpVSCnLQpFgsh9RQBERRawQI1c5HkMKB5coSMiDIww43JG5U5ASnKWnLtQuuH46GifS6hcDmGu6YsyJ-8QCa3ziklc1UuAmulBaNqlcSRidG1opfLEa8tTq6EYMewWjj8KExbLsnCWxZLJhRGSZCrhE9-rGYR9BnT8JBxkrCMsEKFgI8jC1BKcgbfy3k86INrFASgl-TavFMUeMY4JYVJRAMxmiDUJ4ZOGhW7XBFpQYOxF1BNVazFS6qtNM5IA9PWSpJ6bA3IqEsnUwF5DBFwbR6P8Vk0wSw2lrA72uJzQSWYfDCax18njCEGRoenmZ3HjoaUMM9YLU6hZdyaLNhDlAo8k31nSEacMkEjY0fKOHUj6GBbPTB67GLLgueGBUJfCbsV55cgGTIgr-ElgLNx5UIztiQ0Mbxy03TxbOgbms91zaeGsJDUF5BhkyxiLD5qOdDTYGYrDcQaC2tLhFeBZPzZGX_Zzv9k_wE)

---

### Meta

- Is this duplicate/ and interesting question ?
- Is my explanation clear ?

Answer (score 0):

## Interpret a Turing Complete (strict) Subset of your Language

- Write a program which can interpret some programs exactly the same way as your language, where these can be used to model any computation.
- Demonstrate how to do this.
- Your Interpreter may have features your language doesn't have, but your demonstration may not use them.
- You may not use a built-in which interprets the source language, like `eval()`

The feature set does not need to be made of characters or something, you just need to say what it is.

It's [code-golf] until i can think of something better. how do you do tags in markdown?

Example: a javascript interpreter which only allows String.replace, functions, and the ternary conditional thing `? :` may be able to be used as a convoluted slashes emulator.

Discussion:

- This challenge was originally intended to make all languages equally interesting, but I think it still favors turing tarpits and golfing languages.
- As with many Challenges which already exist, this one also gives actually interpreted languages kind of a leg up.
- Making it illegal for turing completeness to arise from interpreter quirks is propably not that important. (like, ACE in my brainfuck interpreter?)
- Banning eval might introduce rules-lawyering on what eval actually is, like, are Regexes allowed? is a built-in which evaluates arithmetic allowed? I'd say yes.
  It might also further favor turing tarpits, though it would nerf golfing languages which propably have an eval construct.
  It might also make the program more laborious to write, obviously, but
- Allowing eval might make writing the program boring as well, as that's an established technique.
- Making this [code-golf] is boring, maybe i should make it about the conciseness of an example program? It wouldn't devolve into HQ9+, but its discriminatory, like how is slashes supposed to calculate a factorial?

Comment: Welcome to cgcc, and interesting idea. Can you define "useful" more (maybe even formally)? Also, don't forget to add a winning criterion (such as [tag:code-golf])

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time here, as this was originally a pure math question that I figured would be more likely to be answered on this site.

Chaitin's incompleteness theorem states that for any theory whose axioms can be computed by a computer program (e.g. Peano arithmetic, ZFC, etc.), there exists a explicit number such that the theory cannot prove that any specific sequence of bits has Kolmogorov complexity larger than that number if the theory is consistent. That is, if the theory is consistent, one cannot prove in this theory that any program which computes this explicit sequence of bits must be of length at larger than this number.

One doesn't really have to know too much about computation theory to do the golfing exercise - the proof of Chaitin's incompleteness comes from the computer program which computes the shortest proof that some explicit number has complexity larger than N. If N is larger then the length of this program, then one has a length at most N program which computes a number which provably cannot be computed by a program with length at most N.

The task I am proposing is to design a Turing tarpit (which doesn't explicitly refer to Peano arithmetic) such that Peano arithmetic cannot prove that any output takes more than a N bit program to compute, for the smallest N. I'm pretty sure N cannot be more than a couple thousand bits, and it's probably the case that it's on the order of a couple hundred bits.

(Note that Peano is implied by second order Peano, which can be formulated with a finite number of axioms, so you don't have to worry about making programs to generate all of the infinite axioms of Peano arithmetic)

Comment: [Welcome to CGCC](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange)! While this is fine for the sandbox, before posting you should take a look at some challenges and make your formatting more alike to them. Regarding the challenge itself - I believe (although I don't know enough logic to prove) that there are programs which PA can't prove don't output any particular output. What prevents `if code=="A": run such a program else: run code as python`, which gives \$N=1\$?

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as this doesn't give a witness to PA not proving that any program has Kolmogorov complexity larger than 1. After all, PA does prove that some machine has Kolmogorov complexity is larger than 1 since PA should decide what the first two programs in basically any language output. 

Sufficient conditions for such a witness is that the program, if it terminates, outputs a number, you can prove PA proves this number has complexity larger than N, the program must halt whenever there is such a proof for any number, and the program is of size at most N.

Comment: But if there's a program which PA can't prove anything about its output (which is hardcoded as part of the language, so a single byte `A` runs it) than it couldn't prove any string has a larger complexity, because that implies `A` doesn't output it which PA can't prove

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that's what I meant about the language not referring to PA or any other specific theory explicitly.

Comment: This seems hard to define properly, because there are problems (like Goodstein's sequences) which don't refer to PA but PA still can't prove, and it seems likely there are problems like that of the format we want.

Comment: I wanted to use PA for concreteness, but a version without a naturality requirement would be one where the program adjustable for any theory encoded by a first-order sentence.

I think the alternative of requiring an actual witness program of the form of the second comment also allows dropping naturality since encoding the meaning of 'A' into arithmetic would be complicated enough to waste bits.

Comment: In particular, since a programming language must be computable, the only way PA might not prove anything about the output of 'A' is if the program assigned to 'A' doesn't terminate. In this particular case, it must halt whenever PA is inconsistent, so it's some explicit function applied to the first proof of inconsistency. Thus, we have a explicit function of the first inconsistency of PA such that it's provable in the base theory (PA or Q) that if PA can prove that this function is not any explicit number, then PA is inconsistent. This might be impossible, and surely can't happen naturally.

Answer (score 0):

## [Literate Programming in Base 26](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266670/literate-programming-in-base-26) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Sandbox questions

- Is the source restriction interesting?
- Is the title OK?
- Should I use base 27 and require the words to be separated by a space?

Answer (score 0):

Positions on the Pickleball Court

My doubles pickleball group often has five people.  Four are playing and one is awaiting the next game.  We can represent the state of the game with a string of five characters like abCde.  This indicates that a and b are playing against c and d with c serving.  We want to write a routine that gives the possible positions after the next rally is complete.  The examples below will assume we start with this configuration.

There are four possible outcomes of a rally.

1)The serving side wins the rally but does not win the game.  The players on the serving side change places and the same player serves, so we go to abdCe.

2)The serving side wins the rally and thereby wins the game.  The players rotate one position right and the serve goes to the first position, so we go to Eabcd

3)The receiving side wins the rally, but the partner of the server has not served yet.  The players stay in position and the serve goes to the partner, so we go to abcDe

4)The receiving side wins the rally and the partner of the server has served.  The players stay in position and the serve goes to the first player of the other side, the one in first or third position.  Here we go to Abcde

Your task is to write a routine that takes a configuration at the start of a rally and returns or prints the four possible configurations at the end of the rally in the order of the possibilities above.  A configuration has the five characters in any order with the server any of the first four.  This is code golf, so the shortest solution wins.  You can use other characters and other ways of indicating the server if you wish, like digits and making the server negative or adding $5$ to the server or putting an asterisk after the server.  There needs to be a clear break between the four possibilities, like a space, a newline, or separate elements of a list.  You can take your input in any convenient way, as a string or array for example.  The characters used should be the same on input and output.

Test cases-input first column, output the remaining four

Abcde bAcde Eabcd aBcde abCde

caBed caeBd Cabed cabEd Cabed

dBace Bdace Edbac Dbace dbAce

bcdAe bcAde Ebcda bcDae Bcdae

Comment: Nice challenge. I’d suggest even more flexibility on input/output, e.g. allowing the output to be a list of lists of digits. Suggest also formatting the test cases as a code block so you have monospacing.

Answer (score 0):

## Seat people as far as possible

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Imagine there are \$n\$ people \$\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}\$ who enter a room in order and sit down in \$n\$ seats, arranged in a row. However, all of these people hate social contact, so they want to sit as far away from each other as possible; specifically, they sit in the set which maximizes the minimum distance from anyone who is already seated. They break ties by sitting in the seat furthest to the left. For example, suppose \$n=5\$. Then the people will sit down in the following order:

```
_ _ _ _ _ 
1 _ _ _ _ 
1 _ _ _ 2
1 _ 3 _ 2
1 4 3 _ 2
1 4 3 5 2
```

Your challenge is, given a positive integer \$n\$, output the final arrangement of \$n\$ people in \$n\$ seats as described above. You can start the numbering of the people from 0 or 1.

#### Test Cases

(In these examples, numbering starts at 1.)

```
0 []
1 [1]
2 [1, 2]
3 [1, 3, 2]
4 [1, 4, 3, 2]
5 [1, 4, 3, 5, 2]
6 [1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2]
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

## Questions

Has this been done before? It feels like would have been (or it reduces to some problem which has been done before), but I don't know how to find out.

Comment: “Imagine there are n people {a1,a2,…,an} who enter a room in order and sit down in n seats, arranged in a row.” Wouldn’t that mean that they all have to sit next to each other, if there are exactly n seats in a row? Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @noodleman Eventually, all the seats will be filled, but the i-th person doesn't necessarily sit in the i-th seat -- they sit in whatever seat in the row maximizes the min distance.

Comment: Oh, I see. So this is a slight variant of the “urinal problem”? There are a few challenges related to it, maybe there’s a dupe under a different title

Comment: Very closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47952/108687 This is like an easier version though so maybe it’s not a dupe

Answer (score 0):

## UTF-8 sum of source code.

Output the sum of the UTF-8 characters codes of your source code.

**Draft notes**

- Seems like there isn't that yet..
- After some feedbacks I think this has nothing interesting or relevant.
  There may be a lot of answers consisting of 150 or answers in the form: print(sum).
- Not going to post it, thanks for feedback.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: When posting this you should also make a CW of all languages `150` is an answer in.

Comment: Do [tag:quine] rules apply?

Comment: @CommandMaster thanks for the feedback, good catch, I'll do it, I'm also hope to see a language where 0 is an answer.

Comment: @Adám yes thank you, I forgot to add a qune tag and rule.

Comment: If quine rules apply, then a 0 score answer is impossible. Is that intended?

Comment: @lyxal no it wasn't, I missed the 0 rule but honestly I would like to allow  0 bytes answers, is it a bad idea? Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd be all for 0 byte answers being allowed, because I already have one in mind :).

Comment: Also, this challenge is very very similar except it's codepage values instead of utf8, and requires non empty programs: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135571/code-point-sum-quine/135586#135586

Comment: @lyxal yes I've seen it and honestly it's more interesting than mine. On second thought I think mine has nothing interesting.. we will have just answers of 150 as stated above and print sum or similar

Answer (score 0):

## Emulate a Turing Complete processor

(As opposed to a Turing-complete processor.)

In the puzzle game Turing Complete, at one stage you get to "build" a processor out of previous parts. This processor has six registers `R0-R5`, a program counter, an input and an output, all 8-bit. All registers default to zero. Unless changed by a condition instruction, the program counter will increment after each instruction.

There are four instructions:

1. `0o0XY` is the "Immediate" instruction. The instruction itself is copied into the `R0` register.
2. `0o1XY` is the "Compute" instruction. The source registers are always `R1` and `R2` and the destination is always `R3`. `Y` can be `0-5` representing one of six computations, `Or`, `Nor`, `Nand`, `And`, `Plus`, `Minus`. `X` is ignored.
3. `0o2XY` is the "Copy" instruction. `X` and `Y` can be `0-5` representing a register or `6` representing the input or output respectively.
4. `0o3XY` is the "Condition" instruction. `Y` can be `0-7` representing one of eight conditions, `False`, `Zero`, `Negative`, `Non-Positive`, `True`, `Non-Zero`, `Non-Negative`, `Positive`. If the signed value in the `R3` register satisfies the condition, the program counter becomes the value of the `R0` register. `X` is ignored.

Your task is to accept a program, which is an array of up to 256 bytes (but your program can use any reasonable data type), an input stream of bytes, and the number of instructions to execute (since there's no `Halt` instruction and there's no guarantee that the computation will ever "finish"), and return the bytes that the program has written to its output.

You can assume that the bytes of the program will only be legal values, although you must ignore `X` for the Compute and Condition instructions. You can assume that the program counter will not index out of the array, although if the input array is 256 bytes then it is possible for the program counter to wrap around since it only has 8 bits.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Stairspin

Given a grid, of n x n size. The elements are indexed so:

```
00 10 20 ...
01 11 21 ...
02 12 22 ...
.. .. .. ...
```

and so on.

There is a very interesting transformation called the *Stairspin*: The 4x4 grid

```
00 10 20 30
01 11 21 31
02 12 22 32
03 13 23 33
```

becomes

```
01 00 10 20
02 12 11 30
03 22 21 31
13 23 33 32
```

after the transformation.

Your task is, given `n` and the index of an element, you must find where the element goes after the Stairspin.

Examples:

- `4 00` -> `10`
- `5 12` -> `11`
- `3 11` -> `11`

Fewest bytes win!

Comment: It's generally discouraged to need to infer the spec from examples, and in this case it takes some hard staring to infer. Am I correct that the Stairspin is dividing the matrix into concentric rings, and rotating each ring clockwise?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yes! That's such a good description. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Produce a secure block cipher round function (1 bit round key; 7 bit message).

Tags: `math`,`encryption`,`cryptography`,`linear algebra`

## Introduction

We are going to need new symmetric encryption functions. We are at the point where we cannot improve the performance of integrated circuits very much simply by shrinking transistors. Furthermore, we are approaching the limits of the energy efficiency of transistors using conventional irreversible computation. The only way to surpass these limits is to use reversible computation. But to get the most out of reversible computation, one needs to use algorithms that are designed for reversible computation. Since the AES encryption protocol was not designed for reversible computation, it is probably a good time for cryptographers to produce, evaluate, and standardize new symmetric encryption functions that are efficient on fully reversible hardware/software. And as a bonus, cryptographic functions are more resistant to side channel attacks when we run them on reversible hardware since irreversible computation not only leaks energy, but irreversible computation leaks some information that can be used to decipher what is being encrypted.

In addition to the need for new cryptographic functions, the rise of AI will bring rise to new cryptoanalytic techniques that can be used to better evaluate the security of block ciphers (this is my personal opinion based on my personal research). Cryptographers can also employ new techniques for evaluating block ciphers including the application of invariants that measure the level of cryptographic security of block ciphers and always give isomorphic block cipher round functions the same level of cryptographic security (this makes it impossible to artificially inflate the security value by relabeling all the possible messages and round keys). Spectral techniques are one way of assigning each block cipher or block cipher round function a specific number that measures its cryptographic security. In this challenge, we shall apply one of these spectral techniques to measure the cryptographic security of some very simple block cipher round functions.

The goal of this challenge is to produce a very simple block cipher round function that minimizes a measure of its cryptographic insecurity. Since this kind of block cipher round function has a microscopic 7 bit message size, it is subject to brute force attacks, and it will probably not have any practical use whatsoever, but we can still measure the level of its cryptographic security in various ways.

The participants in this challenge do not need to have prior experience with evaluating block ciphers and such prior experience probably will not help very much.

## Spectral radius

If \$X\$ is a matrix, then the spectral radius is the value
\$\rho(X)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda\,\text{is an eigenvalue of}\,X\}.\$ It is well known that \$\rho(X)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|X^n\|^{1/n}\$ and this limit does not depend on the matrix norm chosen.

The spectral radius of a complex matrix \$X\$ can often be easily computed. If \$v_0\$ is an arbitrary vector and \$v_{n+1}=\frac{Xv_n}{\|Xv_n\|}\$ for all \$n\$, then \$\|Xv_n\|\$ will converge to the spectral radius \$\rho(X)\$ except in the case when \$X\$ has multiple eigenvalues with maximum absolute value.

## Challenge

Produce a pair of permutations \$(P,Q)\$ of \$\{1,2,...,127,128\}\$ with the smallest associated spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$. The pair of permutations \$(P,Q)\$ should be thought of as the round function for a \$7\$ bit message. If the round key is \$0\$, we perform the transformation \$x\mapsto P(x)\$ to the message \$x\$, and if the round key is 1, then we perform the transformation \$x\mapsto Q(x)\$ to the message \$x\$. A lower spectral radius signifies a greater level of cryptographic security.

Let \$X=\{1,2,...,128\}\$. Let \$Y\$ be the collection of all unordered pairs of distinct elements in the set \$X\$. For example, \$Y\$ contains the pairs \$\{2,3\},\{56,57\},\{2,16\}\$ along with other pairs. The set \$Y\$ contains \$128\cdot 127/2=8128\$ elements.

If \$P\$ is a permutation of \$\{1,...,128\}\$, then the mapping \$P\$ induces a permutation \$P_0\$ of \$Y\$ defined by letting \$P_0(\{a,b\})=\{P(a),P(b)\}\$. Let \$U\$ be the real vector space generated by the basis \$Y\$. Let \$L\$ be the linear functional mapping \$U\$ to the field of real numbers defined by setting \$L(\{x,y\})=1\$ whenever \$x,y\$ are distinct. Let \$V=\ker(U)\$. Then \$V\$ is the subspace of \$U\$ generated by pairs \$\{u,v\}-\{x,y\}\$. We extend the mapping \$P_0\$ to a linear operator \$P_1:U\rightarrow U\$ by linearity. In other words,
\$P_1(\alpha_1\{x_1,y_1\}+\dots+\alpha_n\{x_n,y_n\})=
\alpha_1P_0(\{x_1,y_1\})+\dots+\alpha_nP_0(\{x_n,y_n\})\$
\$=\alpha_1\{P(x_1),P(y_1)\}+\dots+\alpha_n\{P(x_n),P(y_n)\}.\$ Let \$ P_2:V\rightarrow V\$ be the restriction of the operator \$P_1\$. The operator \$P_2\$ is the unique linear operator from \$V\$ to \$V\$ where
\$ P_2(\{u,v\}-\{x,y\})=P_1(\{u,v\})-P_1(\{x,y\})\$ whenever \$\{u,v\},\{x,y\}\in Y\$
Our goal is to minimize the spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$ of the average \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$.

Given a pair of permutations \$P,Q\$ of \$\{1,2,...,127,128\}\$, set
we produce a Markov chain on the set \$\{\{x,y\}:x,y\in\{1,\dots,127,128\},x\neq y\}\$ where we transition from \$\{x,y\}\$ to \$\{P(x),P(y)\}\$ with probability \$1/2\$ and from \$\{x,y\}\$ to \$\{Q(x),Q(y)\}\$ with probability \$1/2\$.  This Markov chain is associated with a double stochastic matrix \$A\$. The doubly stochastic matrix \$A\$ has spectral radius \$1\$, but the second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ measures how quickly powers \$A^n\$ of \$A\$ converge to the matrix where each entry is equal to each other. In other words, the second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ measures how quickly iterating steps in the Markov chain approaches the uniform Markov chain. The second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ is just the spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$.

The averaging operator \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ satisfies the circular law, so the eigenvalues of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ should be approximately uniformly distributed on the disk centered at zero with radius \$\sqrt(2)/2\$. Furthermore, if the permutations \$P,Q\$ are good enough, then the spectral radius of \$(P+Q)/2\$ should be approximately \$\sqrt(2)/2\$.

## Computing the spectral radius

One can easily use power iteration to compute the spectral radius of a sparse matrix except for one tiny problem. The matrix \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ will be a real matrix, and the eigenvalues of real matrices will be symmetric around the real number line. This means that imaginary eigenvalues of real matrices must always come in pairs. Now, since the real number line has zero area and since the eigenvalues of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ satisfy the a sort of circular law (but for \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ the eigenvalues somewhat cluster near the boundary of the disk due to the unitarity of \$P_2,Q_2\$), the matrix \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ is more likely to have a pair of conjugate dominant eigenvalues rather than a single real dominant eigenvalue. We can circumvent this issue by applying the power iteration technique to the complex matrix \$(P_2+(1+i\cdot \epsilon)\cdot Q_2)/2\$ and then slowly decreasing \$\epsilon\$ down to zero so that the power iteration obtains a single dominant eigenvalue/eigenvector pair for \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$.

## Format

In your answer, please specify the permutations P,Q that you use along with the spectral radius of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ (which should be around \$\sqrt{2}/2\$) together with the code or algorithm that you have used to produce the permutations P,Q.

There are two ways that you can specify your permutations.

1. You may write your permutations as tables. For example, `[4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8]` will denote the permutation of {1,...,7,8} where 1->4,2->5,3->6,4->1,5->2,6->3,7->7,8->8.
2. You may also write your permutations as products of disjoint cycles. For example, `(2,6)(3,7)(1,4,8,5)` will denote the permutation of {1,...,7,8} where 2->6,6->2,3->7,7->3,1->4,4->8,8->5,5->1.

## Sample answer (with reduced key size).

Here is a sample answer where (for simplicity) the permutation \$P\$ takes \$5\$ bits as input and out rather than \$7\$ bits (\$P\$ is a permutation of \$\{1,\dots,31,32\}\$).

P:
`(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)(27,28,29)(30,31)`

Q:
`(1,31,29,23,27,12,16,8,6,10,17,2,9,5,24,11,14,7,30,4,19,32,26,15,3,20)(13,18,21,22,28)`

P:
`[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 1, 28, 29, 27, 31, 30,32]`

Q:
`[ 31, 9, 20, 19, 24, 10, 30, 6, 5, 17, 14, 16, 18, 7, 3, 8, 2, 21, 32, 1, 22, 28, 27, 11, 25, 15, 12, 13, 23, 4, 29,
26 ]`

Loss: 0.705873796001...

Observe that the loss is less than \$\sqrt{2}/2\$ but not by much.

We observe that the permutations \$P,Q\$ are uninterpretable, so for these permutations, no information about the algorithm used to produce \$P,Q\$ can be gained from the permutations \$P,Q\$ themselves. Here, the answerer is encouraged to post the code used for generating the permutations \$P,Q\$ or a description of the algorithm or technique used to produce \$P,Q\$.

## Meta (for sandbox only)

I have already asked a couple of questions on this site, but this question is different in several regards, so I need to sandbox this question. While the spectral radius can be computed very quickly to a high degree of accuracy, it will take much computational power to produce \$P,Q\$ where \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$ is sufficiently small. Users with greater computational power will have a slight advantage over those without such computational power. The pair \$(P,Q)\$ will also most likely contain no meaningful information about the algorithm used to obtain \$(P,Q)\$. The permutations \$P,Q\$ in proposed answers will probably look exactly like random permutations and they will probably be completely uninterpretable. Finally, the loss for a pair \$(P,Q)\$ shall be a real number rather than an integer.

If we tried to simplify the Markov chain to the Markov chain with transitions \$x\mapsto P(x)\$ with probability \$1/2\$, and \$x\mapsto Q(x)\$ with probability 1/2, then I already know how to make the the doubly stochastic matrix have characteristic polynomial \$(x-1)x^{127}\$ which means that all the eigenvalues except for one are zero, so we really do need to make the question as complicated as I have made it.

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it's quite hard to read currently (note that in codegolf we use `\$`, not just `$`). You should also given a example for some \$P,Q\$ pair, perhaps smaller

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of the famous 10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND(1));: GOTO 10.
This will produce a maze like pattern with random generated symbols of `/` and `\` with a 50% chance to be printed, and indefinitely.
Such like `///\/\\\//\/\/\\\\\/\///\` and so on. There already exist a book about this at https://10print.org/ which was published in 2011.

I am working at a second book, which among many other things, will show this code in as many diffrent languages as possible. The book will explain how all the codes are working. The idea to this book is to show other approaches and to bring new ideas of programming.

Therefore I call on you to realize the code in as many different programming languages as possible and please explain exactly how and why the code works. If possible, please the use "Try it online!" function. By publishing your codes here, you automatically declare that I may use the code in my book, for which I will of course cite you as the source.

The winners are those with the shortest code for each language. However, it is also a prerequisite that the code is explained at least briefly.

Comment: I think it would make more sense for there to be one winner per language, with the winner being the submission with the shortest code (this is common for code-golf here). Also, please specify how random the decision should be. Does it have to be an exact 50% chance of `/` and 50% chance of ``\``? Finally, please clarify that the program should generate characters like this forever, or until the program is terminated via user input like ctrl+C. May the submission instead be a function that returns some sort of infinite-list structure? (Many languages used on this site have similar structures.)

Comment: Also, [very very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9165/10-print-chr205-5rnd1-goto-10-in-php-or-anything-else-for-that-matter)--minus the licensing stipulation, I suppose.

Comment: @UnrelatedString that's not the only question on this subject. There's also  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25967/15599 where a large number of answers use this. A new question may be closed as a duplicate (and may not generate more answers than the 2 existing questions put together.) A bounty on an existing question might be a good approach, if OP had sufficient reputation to spare. See also https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58653/15599 (given a maze of this type as input, rotate it 45 degrees.)

Answer (score 0):

## Bingo Cards

PDF version [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266879/bingo-cards-pdf). SVG version [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267087/bingo-cards-svg-code).

Tags: `code-golf` `card-games` `file-system`

Also posted [my own implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266925/113678) as a benchmark and to encourage others to answer the question.

Comment: Looking at your sample solution you don't seem to be interested in the part of the code that converts the image to a PDF document, (all the work of converting the canvas to PDF is done by the library you included), so you should probably **allow other image output formats (e.g. HTML, drawing to screen)** to make it easier to solve the challenge in languages with less powerful / no PDF-libraries

Comment: @bsoelch Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I asked another question that accepts the output without requiring any file-write operations or to generate a PDF file. Also gave the link in the Sandbox post.

Answer (score 0):

### Manipulate a set of pixel grids

@sandbox is this a dupe? I couldn't find one and was a bit surprised

Your code should take in one input representing a number of boolean grids and one set of manipulations for each grid, and output a new set of manipulated pixel grids.

The manipulations you must implement are:

- a swap: two pixels which are orthogonally adjacent to each other swap places.
- a toggle: one pixel is toggled.

The grids may be of any rectangular dimension and will have only 2 values. All grids in any one input will be of identical dimension.

Each input grid corresponds to one set of manipulations. There may be any number of manipulations for each grid, including none. A manipulation may undo what a previous manipulation did.

You may choose any format for how the input grids and manipulations must be represented.

Examples:

```
input: 'aa|aa|aa;a |a | a; a|  |a ;' 
2x3 grids, looks like this:
aa | a  |   a
aa | a  |    
aa |  a |  a 
manipulations: '3sa6t1t;4sb1t4t1t;;' (s[a(bove)|b(elow)|l(eft)|r(ight)]=swap at index, t=toggle at index)
output: ' a|aa|a ;a | a|aa; a|  |a ;'
gridified again:
 a | a  |   a
aa |  a |    
a  | aa |  a 

input: 
'|█ █| ██|██ |  █|
 | █ |█ █| ██|  █|
 |███| ██|███|█  |'
manipulations: 'svshttsvsv/5/8/1/7/5;tttttttttt/4/3/6/8/3/;;svshsv/5/5/5;' (s[v(ertically)|h(orizontally)]=swap; tt = toggle)
output:
'|  █| ██|██ |  █|
 |██ |   | ██|  █|
 | ██|  █|███|█  |'
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in each language wins. valid code takes in any size grid and gives an output grid in the same format as the input with provided swaps and toggles preformed on the grid.

Comment: It’s hard to understand what you’re going for, could you please explain it more other than just by adding examples?

Comment: @noodleman sorry, I meant to save it rather than post it so soon after the other one this morning. usually I let it sit in the editor for a couple days while I'm working on it. I'm going to sleep now but I'll look at it closer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

### Draw minimalistic southpark characters

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [image-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-output) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Your task is to output or draw this image of our favorite characters. It is obviously inspired from the logo of Southpark Digital Studios, as shown here: https://southpark.cc.com/, but simplified.

[image: original]

The image has an aspect ratio of 40:12, and everything is aligned on this 40x12 grid. You must output a bitmap image of at least 40 by 12 pixels or a vector graphic.

I've enlarged this images and added thin gray lines for easy pixel counting. The background should be black, white or transparent.

[image: enlarged version]

You must use at least 12 bit color depth (4 bit per RGB channel) and these colors:

```
Stan:    #56a #fdb #a65
Kyle:    #f61 #fdb #3a3
Cartman: #4bc #fdb #d24
Kenny:   #f61 #743 #fdb (outer - middle - inner)
```

## Open questions:

I want a transparent background, which is meaningless (or very difficult) if the image is show on screen.

Comment: Probably should link the actual image for clarity. Also [https://www.southpark.cc.com/](https://www.southpark.cc.com/) doesn't work for me while [https://southpark.cc.com/](https://southpark.cc.com/) does (but redirects to the URL of my country).

Answer (score 0):

## [Which skill to train?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267099/what-skill-to-train)

Answer (score 0):

## [One-dimensional map colouring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267214/72726)

Answer (score 0):

## [Night hike partitioning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/267346/72726)

Answer (score 0):

## The Challenge Challenge

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Your goal is to create a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge that has the longest possible best solution. Post it as an answer to this question, along with the shortest possible solution to that challenge you know of. The number of bytes in that solution is your score, with a higher score being better. To prevent challenges that are boring, bad, not in the spirit of the contest, made of many arbitrary steps, etc, the answer with the most votes will win.

### Rules

- You may not include special scoring in your challenge. All that matters is byte-count.
- You may not intentionally limit the number of languages that can participate in your challenge; any language that can output and input text should be a language that your challenge could be completed in.
- If someone finds a shorter solution to your challenge, you must update your answer with that solution once you see it.
- Your challenge must not need links to be complete; you can't refer to a website for parts of your challenge other than to clarify. This is to prevent challenges that are too complex, with many arbitrary steps. Your solution to your challenge is not included in this rule.
- You may not create a challenge where the goal is simply to output a piece of text ([kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges are not allowed). For example, the [factorial/negation challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109248/mathematics-is-fact-programming-is-not) is allowed, but [outputting an ASCII keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103033/a-keyboard-so-real-you-can-almost-taste-it) is not.

### Requirements for an answer

- A [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge (within the answer)
- The shortest possible solution to it (that you know of), or, if it is too long to fit, a sufficient explanation of what it that so that the program could be constructed without any difficulty.
- The length of that solution

If someone finds an answer to your challenge with a byte count that is shorter than your answer to your challenge, that becomes your new byte count.

The challenge with the most votes wins.

**Questions:**

- Looking at meta pop con questions, I think this satisfies what is needed for one of those. Are there changes I need to make here though?
- Are there any ways I should change this in general?
- Are there comments I haven't fully addressed?

Comment: Would a user post a new challenge as a question, then link to it in an answer to your challenge?

Comment: @Somebody I think the idea was that each answer to this challenge would contain both a spec and a solution.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but I think it’s likely that submissions will devolve to “output the following text” with a solution that uses a built-in compression method.

Comment: @noodleman You are right on both points. I was going to add a rule that stopped people from doing the “output the following text” thing, but forgot when I wrote it up, so I'll add that now.

Comment: I've made changes to the question. Is this ready to post, or are additional changes needed?

Comment: The exception you added doesn't make sense, because the linked Fizz Buzz challenge _is_ a `kolmogorov-complexity` challenge.

Comment: -1, I don't think there is a way to make this challenge interesting - there are too many possible challenges. For example, if someone just makes up a random composition of actions, it's quite likely there isn't a much shorter program for that. How do you even exclude something like \$f(n) = \text{some random number} \cdot n\$, and the myriad of other equivalents?

Comment: @m90 Thanks, I'll change that.

Comment: @CommandMaster The only way I see is to make it a popularity contest. If it isn't, I can't exclude those things. I'm not sure what changes would be needed to make it a popularity contest though, if it even is possible.

Answer (score 0):

## [Translate Japanese hiragana into the flick input method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268604/translate-japanese-hiragana-into-the-flick-input-method)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

Answer (score 0):

## [golf a range with modulus and subtraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/268782/119818)

Answer (score 0):

Output [Some-Text]. You're given its translate in [Some-Language].

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

## Sandbox Notes:

- This seems area where machine learning would work
- Stealing question Allowed

Answer (score 0):

### Golf golfing a range with modulus and subtraction

In [this other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268782/) question I asked you to golf code which finds an equation transforming a list of unique numbers down to a minimal list. For this question, I'm asking you to write code which golfs that equation. In the other question we found that `((l-5)%99-94)%98` is a valid equation that turns `l=[2,1,5,3,99,7,6]` into `[2,1,4,3,0,6,5]`, but if we do some more thinking, we can see that there are shorter ways to do this: `(l%91-5)%8` gives the list `[5,4,0,6,3,2,1]` and `l%95-1` gives the list `[1,0,4,2,3,6,5]`. Rather than golfing the code used to generate the equation, in this question you are looking for an algorithm that produces the shortest final equation.

To be a valid answer, your code must give an equation that transforms a provided list of unique, non-negative integers into a list of unique, non-negative integers in the range 0 to `len(list)-1`. You are scored for the length of the equation that you output rather than the length of your code. Each operation is one point, so an output of `((l-5)%99-94)%98` would score 4, `(l%91-5)%8` would score 3, and `l%95-1` would score 2. In a tie, the score is the character length of the complete equation including parenthesis, so `((l-5)%99-94)%98` would score 16, `(l%91-5)%8` would score 10, and `l%95-1` would score 6. Lowest score wins, as with normal code golf.

Different lists may give better scores using some algorithms over others, so we need to test your code to be sure that it is the best for many different lists. The score you list on your answer is the average score your code gets on all lists of 1-15 digits with values in the range 0-63 (say the average primary *and* secondary score in your answer). As this question is about the algorithm rather than the code length, you should explain your method as well. If you can prove that your method will always give the best possible score, I will mark your answer as accepted and (if it's simple enough) use your method as the example explanation in the other question. If this happens, I will also edit this question to include an explanation of your algorithm and this question will become a normal code-golf question where everyone implements that algorithm or an equivalent in as few bytes as possible in each language.

As the lists your code is tested against are finite in length and have a maximum value, you could theoretically brute-force the shortest solution by trying every possible modulus and subtraction value and returning the shortest. To prevent this, your code should run in less than `O(r^l)` time, where r is the range and l is the length.

@sandbox, What do you think is a good range? Should it be 1-7 digits, 1-31 digits? Values from 0-31, values from 0-127? Or should it be decimal ranges, 1-9 digits ranging from 0-99?

Also, what other tags?

Comment: Is there anything preventing solutions from doing a boring, trivially optimal, bruteforce solution?

Comment: @CommandMaster do you think that looks good for preventing bruteforce solutions?

Comment: Requiring to build the equation one operand at a time seems overly restrictive, and it's also not very clearly defined. What kind of calculations can you do on the array, before you actually "build" the solution?

Comment: @CommandMaster yeah, I think that worked better in my head than it would in practice. I can't think of any other way to restrict bruteforce solutions without also restricting algorithmic solutions, do you have any ideas? or if not; is it fine to just have 'the brute force solution does not count' in the question?

Comment: I think the best way to prevent brute force would just be to restrict the runtime, and have larger inputs

Comment: @CommandMaster do you think that works to prevent bruteforce? and also for larger inputs what were you thinking would be a good amount? I think rn it's checking around 2e14 lists

Answer (score 0):

## [Unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269000/unnecessary-fluff)

#### Sandbox note

There is a fairly efficient way to calculate this \$h\$, which might be interesting. Do you think I should require polynomial time, or being able to calculate all the testcases in a minute?

Answer (score 0):

## Output a 1-digit integer log table

Log tables were originally used for multiplication, since \$ x \times y = \exp(\log x + \log y) \$, superseding the use of trigonometric functions for this purpose. A log table I used in school back in the day had 900 main entries and then some interpolation entries you could use to give yourself almost an extra digit of accuracy.

However, if you were building a mechanical computer, you wouldn't need to have thousands of entries, as you could just program it to do long multiplication; the stumbling block is actually multiplying two digits together in the first place.

One approach to this is to use something called an Irish logarithm table. This is basically a pair of integer mappings \$ f \$ and \$ g \$ such that \$ g(f(x) + f(y)) = x \times y \$ for all \$ x, y \in \{ 0..9 \} \$.

For this challenge I would like you to output any two integer mappings with that property, in any reasonable format. In particular, since the length of the `f` mapping is always ten, there is no need to separate the `f` and `g` mappings in your output.

Note that while the `f` mapping maps from `0` to `9`, the `g` mapping will have gaps because some of its indices won't correspond to the sum of two values of `f`. You can handle this either by outputting the mapping as a dictionary or by padding the output array with a suitable filler value.

Excluding the filler value, the `g` mapping only needs to output the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 49, 54, 56, 63, 64, 72, 81`.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or function that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Comment: Any potentially shorter way than log(x)*999?

Comment: @l4m2 What integer are you using for an input of `0`?

Comment: Also, I can see I should have specified non-negative integers.

Comment: And I might need to include the highest index of `g` in the scoring somehow.

Comment: Is there a reason for outputting mappings and not just implementing the functions?

Comment: @CommandMaster It's to help you construct a mechanical calculator which can do lookup tables but not function calls.

Comment: I just don't think that requiring answers to do `return [f(i) for i in range(10)]` is interesting - do you have solutions constructing these mappings in a different way?

Comment: @CommandMaster I wasn't expecting there to be a closed form for `f` and `g`; if you have one then this question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: There is discrete log mod 83, although that isn't really a closed form and you need to do something for 0

Answer (score 0):

### [Shortest path to open a letter lock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269060/shortest-path-to-open-a-letter-lock)

Comment: I think this is easier than you intend it to be, but fair enough. Can the input be taken as a list of indices of the alphabet rather than a string / list of codepoints?

Comment: @noodleman i think that would ruin the theme here, i wasnt even sure if i should include the list of letters instead of the full string

Comment: Well, taking a string as a list of characters is an I/O default on this site. I would personally recommend letting letters of the alphabet be taken as indices, as that's just an extra step that most solutions will have to use and could be very long in some languages. Alternatively, a slightly more interesting variant of this challenge would be to take an arrangement of the alphabet as input (like `abc...z` or `azbycx...` or `ajoifqw...`) rather than always using the same alphabet.

Comment: @noodleman From what I have seen, allowing letters to be replaced with indices is generally not an option for input in challenges like this, especially when the whole point is to have two "words" to switch between

Answer (score 0):

## Circle to split points

Given two sets of points, decide whether there's a circle that split them.

- Treating points exactly on circle as inside or outside are allowed as radius +/-eps
- Maybe one input forced inside and one outside?

Answer (score 0):

## [Find the child anagrams of a word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269222/91472)

Answer (score 0):

## Battle Simulator KOTH

### Challenge

In this king-of-the-hill challenge, each player/bot is assigned a random character and is then put in a 10x10 grid. Each character has 2 different abilities and 1 ultimate ability. The goal of each player is to be the last man standing.

### Rules

At the start of each game, each bot is given 10 health and 10 points to freely distribute through these 3 categories:

**Speed** (for example if you have three speed you can go up 2 and left 1 in one turn)

**Dexterity** (the more dexterity you have the less chance you have of getting hit by an attack. For example if you have 3 dexterity and was attacked by an attack that does 4 damage, there is a 3 * 3 = 9% chance you dodge it where the second 3 is a constant.)

**Defense** (let's say you have 3 defense and was hit by an attack that does 5 damage. Then you will take a random amount of damage from 1 to 1 where the second 1 is attack strength - defense / 2)

Each bot is also randomly assigned one of these two characters:

##### Swordsman:

- Normal ability (Stab):

  - 0 (turns of) recharge
  - does 1 damage
  - hits the three tiles in front of him
- Special ability 1 (Circle Slash):

  - 2 recharge
  - does 2 damage
  - hits the 9 tiles surrounding him
- Special ability 2 (Multi-Sword):

  - 4 recharge
  - does 2 damage
  - hits the three closest enemies
- ###### Ultimate Ability (Explosion):

  - 10 recharge (cannot be used at beginning of game)
  - does 6 damage
  - hits the first player in front of him and triggers a 6x6 explosion

##### Wizard

- Normal ability (Burn):

  - 0 recharge
  - does 2 damage
  - hits the tile directly in front of him
- Special ability 1 (Freeze):

  - 3 recharge
  - does 1 damage
  - freezes the first enemy in front of him for 2 turns
- Special ability 2 (Zap):

  - 5 recharge
  - does 2 damage
  - zaps the five closest enemies, twice
- ###### Ultimate ability (Weaken):

  - 15 recharge (cannot be used at the beginning of game)
  - 0 damage
  - halves all stats of all other players (can stack)

However, there is a twist. Each bot does **NOT** know what character type they are.

### Turns

Each turn, every player does one of the following:

- Do nothing (lol)
- Use an attack that is not on cooldown (attacks can miss)
- Move

When a player is hit by an attack, their health goes down by how strong the attack is and is also hit by status effects should the attack have them. If a player's health reaches zero, they are defeated (e. g. removed from the game) and are replaced by a rock other players may not pass through. If a player tries to move through a rock or another player, they simply end up in front of it and do not go through.

The game ends in 100 turns or only one player remains, whichever comes first. If the game lasts that long, the winner is the one with most eliminations. If there still is a tie, all tied bots receive a point for that round. Of course, if only one player remains before the 100 turns, that player wins the round and gets a point.

### How bots work

Bots should be written in Python, but I will try to support other mainline languages by translating them into Python.

The basic boilerplate code for a bot is this:

```
class MyBotThatWillHopefullyWin(Bot):
    def __init(self)__:
        super().__init__(self, <speed>, <dexterity>, <defense>)
    
    def turn():
        <insert logic>
```

The turn function is basically your main function and will be executed for every turn your bot is alive for. It should return one of four values:

- `return "move", <x>, <y>` to move (duh.) Or in more specific terms, `Tuple[Union[str, Union[int, int]]]` where `str` must be `move` and `abs(x + y)` must be <= `self.speed` (the first value you put in the super definition.) If this condition is not satisfied, nothing happens that turn. Note how you cannot leave the confines of the 10x10 grid or move and attack or vice versa in the same turn.
- `return "basic attack"` to do the (randomly predetermined) charector's basic attack.
- `return "ability", <ability number>` to do one of the charector's abilities. `1` is the charector's first special ability, `2` is the second, and `3` is the ultimate ability. If the ability numberis not in the range 1-3 or the attack is still on cooldown, nothing happens.
- `return "nothing"` to do nothing. But why tho?

Here is the list of methods bots have available to them: (accessed by `self.<method name(<parameters, if any>)`

Comment: What do players know? Only the location of enemies and whether they're dead, and their own health?

Comment: @CommandMaster I'll add that in when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

## The Elements Of The Periodic Table!

The challenge is to take input as an integer between 1 and 118 inclusive, then output the name of the chemical element with that atomic number.

Capitalisation as well as trailing and leading whitespace do not matter.

You should call the chemical elements by their 2024 names, for example 113 outputs `nihonium` and not `ununtrium`.

For ease of golfing, element 16 can be either `sulfur` or `sulphur`.

Test cases:

```
1 -> hydrogen
2 -> helium
3 -> lithium
4 -> beryllium
5 -> boron
6 -> carbon
117 -> tennessine
118 -> oganesson
```

Use any language, shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Looks like a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## ahee bee cee dee ehee fee...

Given a string with no whitespace, replace the first letter of the string with every letter in the english lowercase alphabet. However, if the input string starts with a vowel (excluding y), then there should be an extra `h` after (the prefixes `aeiou`.)

For example, if the input string is `ee`, your program should output:

```
ahe
be
ce
de
ehe
fe
ge
he
ihe
je
ke
le
me
ne
ohe
pe
qe
re
see
te
uhe
ve
we
xe
ye
ze
```

Comment: Where do `eht` come?

Comment: @I4m2 Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## What are the current football (soccer) league positions?

[English football is structured into leagues with varying numbers of clubs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Football_League) For example, the EFL Championship has 24 clubs. During each season, each side will play every other side twice (once at home and once away); for a 24-club league, this gives 46 matches for each team in total. Teams score three points for a win, one for a draw and none for a loss. The ranking in the league is determined by:

1. Points gained
2. Goal difference
3. Goals scored
4. Head-to-head record
5. Alphabetical order (unless the position is relevant for a promotion, relegation or play-off space, but this has never happened, and will not need to be handled for this challenge)

### Challenge

#### Input

- A list of games played so far in the league, indicating the home team, away team, score for
  the home team and score for the away team.

#### Desired output

- A list of teams in position order, either highest to lowest or lowest to highest (but must be consistent for all inputs).

#### Rules and assumptions

- Teams can be represented in whatever way the answerer prefers. You may take actual team names, integers, or any other standard input provided the team name does not somehow encode its position in the league and none of the default loopholes are violated. Team names in the output should match those in the input.
- All teams in the league will have played at least once at the time of asking, though they will not necessarily have all played each other by that stage, nor will they have necessarily played the same number of matches. Of note, the interim league tables for English football show the number of matches played, but the relative positioning does not take into account that one team may have matches in hand.
- You do not need to provide any of the stats typically presented in a football league table, just the ordering of teams.
- Default loopholes and standard I/O methods apply
- Although input is flexible, the home/away ordering should be preserved (so it is not valid to require the winning team always be listed first)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Example input

```
[
[["Leeds United",2],["Preston North End",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Cardiff City",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Rotherham United",1]],
[["Norwich City",2],["West Bromwich Albion",0]],
[["Stoke City",1],["Birmingham City",2]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",2],["Millwall",0]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",1],["Coventry City",2]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Watford",1]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Southampton",3]],
[["Sunderland",0],["Hull City",1]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Watford",2]],
[["Ipswich Town",2],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Millwall",1],["Middlesbrough",3]],
[["Rotherham United",0],["Stoke City",1]],
[["Southampton",4],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",4],["Blackburn Rovers",1]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Cardiff City",0],["Leeds United",3]],
[["Birmingham City",2],["Swansea City",2]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Coventry City",3],["Leicester City",1]],
[["Hull City",1],["Norwich City",2]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",3],["Hull City",1]],
[["Norwich City",1],["Southampton",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",2],["Rotherham United",2]],
[["Bristol City",0],["Millwall",1]],
[["Leeds United",3],["Birmingham City",0]],
[["Leicester City",4],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Coventry City",3]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Watford",3]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Ipswich Town",0]],
[["Swansea City",1],["West Bromwich Albion",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Cardiff City",2]],
[["Sunderland",2],["Preston North End",0]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Leeds United",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",0],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Cardiff City",0],["Leicester City",2]],
[["Coventry City",2],["Swansea City",2]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Hull City",3],["Blackburn Rovers",2]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Millwall",1],["Norwich City",0]],
[["Preston North End",0],["Sheffield Wednesday",1]],
[["Watford",1],["Stoke City",1]],
[["Birmingham City",0],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Southampton",2],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Ipswich Town",1],["Leicester City",1]],
[["Birmingham City",1],["Stoke City",3]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Middlesbrough",0]],
[["Southampton",5],["Swansea City",0]],
[["Hull City",0],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Huddersfield Town",3],["Blackburn Rovers",0]],
[["Coventry City",2],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Plymouth Argyle",2]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Norwich City",0]],
[["Watford",1],["Bristol City",4]],
[["Millwall",2],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Leeds United",1]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Millwall",0]],
[["Sunderland",0],["Coventry City",3]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",1],["Cardiff City",2]],
[["Leicester City",3],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",0],["Southampton",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Birmingham City",3]],
[["Norwich City",2],["Huddersfield Town",0]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["West Bromwich Albion",0]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Watford",2]],
[["Leeds United",4],["Ipswich Town",0]],
[["Swansea City",2],["Preston North End",1]],
[["Bristol City",3],["Hull City",2]],
[["Birmingham City",2],["Leicester City",3]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Stoke City",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Rotherham United",2]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Southampton",4],["Blackburn Rovers",0]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",2],["Queens Park Rangers",1]],
[["Preston North End",1],["Watford",5]],
[["Millwall",1],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Leeds United",1],["Coventry City",1]],
[["Hull City",3],["Cardiff City",0]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Sunderland",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",2],["Norwich City",2]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Hull City",2]],
[["Cardiff City",0],["Birmingham City",1]],
[["Coventry City",1],["Southampton",1]],
[["Norwich City",3],["Sheffield Wednesday",1]],
[["Leicester City",3],["Millwall",2]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",0],["Plymouth Argyle",0]],
[["Sunderland",1],["Leeds United",0]],
[["Watford",1],["Ipswich Town",2]],
[["Stoke City",1],["Swansea City",1]],
[["Rotherham United",0],["West Bromwich Albion",2]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Preston North End",3]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",2],["Bristol City",1]],
[["Norwich City",0],["Preston North End",0]],
[["Cardiff City",1],["Millwall",0]],
[["Leicester City",4],["Plymouth Argyle",0]],
[["Middlesbrough",0],["Ipswich Town",2]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Bristol City",1]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",2],["Hull City",0]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Sheffield Wednesday",1]],
[["Watford",1],["Southampton",1]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Swansea City",2]],
[["Sunderland",2],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",0],["Leeds United",2]],
[["Coventry City",2],["Birmingham City",0]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Norwich City",2]],
[["Millwall",1],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Birmingham City",0],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Hull City",1],["Watford",2]],
[["Ipswich Town",2],["Coventry City",1]],
[["Leeds United",3],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",2],["Stoke City",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",3],["Blackburn Rovers",1]],
[["Southampton",2],["Cardiff City",0]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Leicester City",2]],
[["Preston North End",0],["Queens Park Rangers",2]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Millwall",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",4],["Birmingham City",2]],
[["Leeds United",3],["Swansea City",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",1],["Leicester City",1]],
[["Southampton",1],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Sunderland",1],["Huddersfield Town",2]],
[["Watford",3],["Norwich City",2]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",4],["Stoke City",2]],
[["Middlesbrough",4],["Preston North End",0]],
[["Hull City",4],["Rotherham United",1]],
[["Coventry City",1],["Plymouth Argyle",0]],
[["Cardiff City",0],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",2],["Ipswich Town",0]],
[["Millwall",0],["Coventry City",3]],
[["Birmingham City",2],["Sheffield Wednesday",1]],
[["Bristol City",3],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Southampton",1]],
[["Leicester City",2],["Watford",0]],
[["Norwich City",1],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Preston North End",1],["Cardiff City",2]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Blackburn Rovers",3]],
[["Swansea City",2],["Hull City",2]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",2],["Sunderland",0]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Leeds United",1]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Norwich City",3]],
[["Leeds United",2],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Coventry City",0],["Stoke City",0]],
[["Hull City",1],["Huddersfield Town",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Swansea City",2]],
[["Southampton",2],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Leicester City",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",0],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",0],["Millwall",4]],
[["Watford",5],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Sunderland",3],["Birmingham City",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Preston North End",2]],
[["Rotherham United",2],["Ipswich Town",2]],
[["Norwich City",1],["Blackburn Rovers",3]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",3],["Hull City",1]],
[["Swansea City",0],["Sunderland",0]],
[["Birmingham City",2],["Ipswich Town",2]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Huddersfield Town",0],["Watford",0]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Queens Park Rangers",1]],
[["Millwall",0],["Southampton",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Middlesbrough",3]],
[["Preston North End",3],["Coventry City",2]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Cardiff City",0]],
[["Leicester City",0],["Leeds United",1]],
[["Coventry City",0],["West Bromwich Albion",2]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",2],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Plymouth Argyle",2]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",0],["Swansea City",1]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Hull City",1],["Preston North End",0]],
[["Middlesbrough",0],["Stoke City",2]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Leicester City",2]],
[["Sunderland",3],["Norwich City",1]],
[["Watford",2],["Millwall",2]],
[["Leeds United",4],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Southampton",3],["Birmingham City",1]],
[["Stoke City",1],["Leeds United",0]],
[["Rotherham United",2],["Coventry City",0]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Southampton",2]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Bristol City",0],["Ipswich Town",1]],
[["Birmingham City",0],["Hull City",2]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",2],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Leicester City",1],["Sunderland",0]],
[["Swansea City",0],["Watford",1]],
[["Norwich City",1],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Millwall",1],["Blackburn Rovers",2]],
[["Huddersfield Town",0],["Cardiff City",4]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Birmingham City",0]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Cardiff City",0]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Coventry City",0]],
[["Huddersfield Town",2],["Queens Park Rangers",1]],
[["Hull City",1],["Southampton",2]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",0],["Plymouth Argyle",0]],
[["Norwich City",2],["Leeds United",3]],
[["Stoke City",2],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Leicester City",3]],
[["Watford",1],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Preston North End",1],["Millwall",1]],
[["Cardiff City",1],["Watford",1]],
[["Southampton",1],["Rotherham United",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",0],["Huddersfield Town",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",0],["Blackburn Rovers",4]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",1],["Swansea City",3]],
[["Millwall",2],["Hull City",2]],
[["Leicester City",2],["Stoke City",0]],
[["Leeds United",2],["Bristol City",1]],
[["Ipswich Town",4],["Preston North End",2]],
[["Coventry City",1],["Norwich City",1]],
[["Sunderland",0],["Middlesbrough",4]],
[["Birmingham City",3],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Bristol City",2]],
[["Sunderland",2],["Watford",0]],
[["Leicester City",3],["Preston North End",0]],
[["Leeds United",1],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Coventry City",1],["Blackburn Rovers",0]],
[["Swansea City",2],["Norwich City",1]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Southampton",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",0],["Millwall",2]],
[["Middlesbrough",2],["Cardiff City",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Hull City",0]],
[["Birmingham City",4],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Leicester City",4]],
[["Huddersfield Town",1],["Ipswich Town",1]],
[["Millwall",0],["Swansea City",3]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Bristol City",2],["Stoke City",3]],
[["Hull City",1],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Norwich City",2],["Birmingham City",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Coventry City",3]],
[["Watford",2],["Middlesbrough",3]],
[["Preston North End",0],["West Bromwich Albion",4]],
[["Southampton",3],["Leeds United",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",0],["Sunderland",3]],
[["Coventry City",1],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Sunderland",0],["Cardiff City",1]],
[["Stoke City",1],["Hull City",3]],
[["Leeds United",3],["Watford",0]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",0],["Millwall",0]],
[["Swansea City",3],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Preston North End",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",6],["Norwich City",2]],
[["Middlesbrough",2],["Southampton",1]],
[["Leicester City",1],["Bristol City",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",4],["Blackburn Rovers",3]],
[["Birmingham City",0],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Norwich City",0],["Leicester City",2]],
[["Watford",2],["West Bromwich Albion",2]],
[["Millwall",3],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Hull City",0],["Leeds United",0]],
[["Huddersfield Town",2],["Stoke City",2]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Sunderland",3]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",1],["Middlesbrough",1]],
[["Bristol City",4],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Southampton",0],["Ipswich Town",1]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Swansea City",1]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Birmingham City",1]],
[["Cardiff City",3],["Coventry City",2]],
[["Millwall",0],["Leeds United",3]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Swansea City",0]],
[["Bristol City",0],["West Bromwich Albion",0]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",2],["Middlesbrough",1]],
[["Huddersfield Town",2],["Rotherham United",0]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",0],["Ipswich Town",1]],
[["Norwich City",1],["Stoke City",0]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",1],["Sunderland",3]],
[["Watford",2],["Birmingham City",0]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Southampton",1],["Leicester City",4]],
[["Hull City",1],["Coventry City",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Blackburn Rovers",0]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Cardiff City",2]],
[["Leeds United",0],["Sheffield Wednesday",0]],
[["Leicester City",0],["Hull City",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",0],["Queens Park Rangers",2]],
[["Coventry City",3],["Watford",3]],
[["Rotherham United",2],["Norwich City",1]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",1],["Huddersfield Town",2]],
[["Stoke City",0],["Preston North End",2]],
[["Sunderland",5],["Southampton",0]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Bristol City",2]],
[["Birmingham City",1],["Millwall",1]],
[["Watford",0],["Blackburn Rovers",1]],
[["Ipswich Town",3],["Leeds United",4]],
[["Birmingham City",2],["Plymouth Argyle",1]],
[["Cardiff City",2],["Sheffield Wednesday",1]],
[["Coventry City",0],["Sunderland",0]],
[["Huddersfield Town",0],["Norwich City",4]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Swansea City",1]],
[["Millwall",1],["Stoke City",0]],
[["Rotherham United",1],["Leicester City",2]],
[["Southampton",2],["Queens Park Rangers",1]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",4],["Middlesbrough",2]],
[["Hull City",1],["Bristol City",1]],
[["Norwich City",3],["Millwall",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",1],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Bristol City",0],["Birmingham City",2]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",1],["Hull City",2]],
[["Leicester City",2],["Cardiff City",1]],
[["Sunderland",2],["Rotherham United",1]],
[["Queens Park Rangers",0],["Ipswich Town",1]],
[["Stoke City",1],["Watford",0]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Coventry City",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",0],["Preston North End",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",1],["Southampton",2]],
[["Leeds United",1],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["Millwall",0],["Bristol City",1]],
[["Birmingham City",1],["Leeds United",0]],
[["Cardiff City",1],["Queens Park Rangers",2]],
[["Hull City",4],["Sheffield Wednesday",2]],
[["Ipswich Town",2],["Stoke City",0]],
[["Huddersfield Town",0],["Leicester City",1]],
[["Preston North End",2],["Sunderland",1]],
[["Southampton",4],["Norwich City",4]],
[["Watford",0],["Plymouth Argyle",0]],
[["West Bromwich Albion",3],["Swansea City",2]],
[["Rotherham United",2],["Blackburn Rovers",2]],
[["Coventry City",3],["Middlesbrough",0]],
[["Sunderland",1],["Ipswich Town",2]],
[["Leeds United",2],["Cardiff City",2]],
[["Leicester City",2],["Coventry City",1]],
[["Blackburn Rovers",2],["West Bromwich Albion",1]],
[["Watford",4],["Queens Park Rangers",0]],
[["Swansea City",1],["Birmingham City",1]],
[["Stoke City",4],["Rotherham United",1]],
[["Plymouth Argyle",3],["Huddersfield Town",1]],
[["Norwich City",2],["Hull City",1]],
[["Middlesbrough",0],["Millwall",1]],
[["Bristol City",1],["Preston North End",1]],
[["Sheffield Wednesday",1],["Southampton",2]]
]
```

#### Points, goal difference, goals for (don’t need to be output)

```
65 34 55 Leicester City
58 21 53 Southampton
58 16 50 Ipswich Town
54 24 50 Leeds United
45 13 40 West Bromwich Albion
43 13 43 Coventry City
42 4 42 Hull City
41 3 46 Norwich City
40 7 45 Watford
40 6 37 Sunderland
40 1 42 Middlesbrough
38 -12 34 Preston North End
37 0 31 Bristol City
37 -4 35 Cardiff City
33 0 47 Plymouth Argyle
33 -6 38 Swansea City
33 -12 41 Blackburn Rovers
32 -7 29 Millwall
32 -7 27 Stoke City
32 -10 34 Birmingham City
27 -18 28 Huddersfield Town
24 -15 24 Queens Park Rangers
22 -24 22 Sheffield Wednesday
19 -27 25 Rotherham United
```

#### Output for this example (from highest to lowest)

```
Leicester City
Southampton
Ipswich Town
Leeds United
West Bromwich Albion
Coventry City
Hull City
Norwich City
Watford
Sunderland
Middlesbrough
Preston North End
Bristol City
Cardiff City
Plymouth Argyle
Swansea City
Blackburn Rovers
Millwall
Stoke City
Birmingham City
Huddersfield Town
Queens Park Rangers
Sheffield Wednesday
Rotherham United
```

#### Alternative with integers for team names

```
[
[[9,2],[15,1]],
[[14,3],[4,1]],
[[11,1],[17,1]],
[[13,2],[24,0]],
[[20,1],[1,2]],
[[16,2],[12,0]],
[[18,1],[5,2]],
[[2,1],[6,1]],
[[3,1],[23,1]],
[[22,1],[19,3]],
[[21,0],[7,1]],
[[16,1],[23,2]],
[[8,2],[21,1]],
[[12,1],[11,3]],
[[17,0],[20,1]],
[[19,4],[18,0]],
[[24,4],[2,1]],
[[6,1],[14,1]],
[[4,0],[9,3]],
[[1,2],[22,2]],
[[15,2],[3,0]],
[[5,3],[10,1]],
[[7,1],[13,2]],
[[18,3],[7,1]],
[[13,1],[19,1]],
[[2,2],[17,2]],
[[3,0],[12,1]],
[[9,3],[1,0]],
[[10,4],[6,1]],
[[11,1],[5,3]],
[[14,3],[23,3]],
[[20,0],[8,0]],
[[22,1],[24,0]],
[[16,1],[4,2]],
[[21,2],[15,0]],
[[24,1],[9,0]],
[[8,0],[16,0]],
[[4,0],[10,2]],
[[5,2],[22,2]],
[[6,1],[11,2]],
[[7,3],[2,2]],
[[17,1],[21,1]],
[[12,1],[13,0]],
[[15,0],[18,1]],
[[23,1],[20,1]],
[[1,0],[3,0]],
[[19,2],[14,1]],
[[8,1],[10,1]],
[[1,1],[20,3]],
[[17,1],[11,0]],
[[19,5],[22,0]],
[[7,0],[21,1]],
[[6,3],[2,0]],
[[5,2],[18,0]],
[[4,2],[14,2]],
[[24,1],[13,0]],
[[23,1],[3,4]],
[[12,2],[16,0]],
[[15,2],[9,1]],
[[20,0],[12,0]],
[[21,0],[5,3]],
[[18,1],[4,2]],
[[10,3],[17,0]],
[[16,0],[19,1]],
[[14,3],[1,3]],
[[13,2],[6,0]],
[[11,1],[24,0]],
[[2,1],[23,2]],
[[9,4],[8,0]],
[[22,2],[15,1]],
[[3,3],[7,2]],
[[1,2],[10,3]],
[[24,1],[20,1]],
[[14,3],[17,2]],
[[22,1],[11,2]],
[[19,4],[2,0]],
[[18,2],[16,1]],
[[15,1],[23,5]],
[[12,1],[6,1]],
[[9,1],[5,1]],
[[7,3],[4,0]],
[[3,1],[21,0]],
[[8,2],[13,2]],
[[11,1],[7,2]],
[[4,0],[1,1]],
[[5,1],[19,1]],
[[13,3],[18,1]],
[[10,3],[12,2]],
[[16,0],[14,0]],
[[21,1],[9,0]],
[[23,1],[8,2]],
[[20,1],[22,1]],
[[17,0],[24,2]],
[[6,1],[15,3]],
[[2,2],[3,1]],
[[13,0],[15,0]],
[[4,1],[12,0]],
[[10,4],[14,0]],
[[11,0],[8,2]],
[[6,1],[3,1]],
[[16,2],[7,0]],
[[20,0],[18,1]],
[[23,1],[19,1]],
[[17,1],[22,2]],
[[21,2],[24,1]],
[[2,0],[9,2]],
[[5,2],[1,0]],
[[3,1],[13,2]],
[[12,1],[21,1]],
[[1,0],[17,0]],
[[7,1],[23,2]],
[[8,2],[5,1]],
[[9,3],[11,2]],
[[22,1],[6,1]],
[[14,2],[20,1]],
[[18,3],[2,1]],
[[19,2],[4,0]],
[[24,1],[10,2]],
[[15,0],[16,2]],
[[8,3],[12,1]],
[[2,4],[1,2]],
[[9,3],[22,1]],
[[18,1],[10,1]],
[[19,1],[3,0]],
[[21,1],[6,2]],
[[23,3],[13,2]],
[[16,4],[20,2]],
[[11,4],[15,0]],
[[7,4],[17,1]],
[[5,1],[14,0]],
[[4,0],[24,1]],
[[24,2],[8,0]],
[[12,0],[5,3]],
[[1,2],[18,1]],
[[3,3],[11,2]],
[[6,1],[19,1]],
[[10,2],[23,0]],
[[13,1],[16,0]],
[[15,1],[4,2]],
[[20,0],[2,3]],
[[22,2],[7,2]],
[[14,2],[21,0]],
[[17,1],[9,1]],
[[4,2],[13,3]],
[[9,2],[14,1]],
[[5,0],[20,0]],
[[7,1],[6,0]],
[[8,3],[22,2]],
[[19,2],[24,1]],
[[11,1],[10,0]],
[[16,0],[3,0]],
[[18,0],[12,4]],
[[23,5],[17,0]],
[[21,3],[1,1]],
[[2,1],[15,2]],
[[17,2],[8,2]],
[[13,1],[2,3]],
[[24,3],[7,1]],
[[22,0],[21,0]],
[[1,2],[8,2]],
[[3,1],[18,0]],
[[6,0],[23,0]],
[[17,1],[16,1]],
[[12,0],[19,1]],
[[14,3],[11,3]],
[[15,3],[5,2]],
[[20,0],[4,0]],
[[10,0],[9,1]],
[[5,0],[24,2]],
[[18,2],[17,0]],
[[8,3],[14,2]],
[[2,0],[22,1]],
[[4,2],[3,0]],
[[7,1],[15,0]],
[[11,0],[20,2]],
[[16,1],[10,2]],
[[21,3],[13,1]],
[[23,2],[12,2]],
[[9,4],[6,1]],
[[19,3],[1,1]],
[[20,1],[9,0]],
[[17,2],[5,0]],
[[15,2],[19,2]],
[[14,3],[18,0]],
[[3,0],[8,1]],
[[1,0],[7,2]],
[[24,2],[16,0]],
[[10,1],[21,0]],
[[22,0],[23,1]],
[[13,1],[11,2]],
[[12,1],[2,2]],
[[6,0],[4,4]],
[[11,1],[1,0]],
[[2,1],[4,0]],
[[3,1],[5,0]],
[[6,2],[16,1]],
[[7,1],[19,2]],
[[24,0],[14,0]],
[[13,2],[9,3]],
[[20,2],[21,1]],
[[22,1],[10,3]],
[[23,1],[18,0]],
[[15,1],[12,1]],
[[4,1],[23,1]],
[[19,1],[17,1]],
[[18,0],[6,0]],
[[16,0],[2,4]],
[[14,1],[22,3]],
[[12,2],[7,2]],
[[10,2],[20,0]],
[[9,2],[3,1]],
[[8,4],[15,2]],
[[5,1],[13,1]],
[[21,0],[11,4]],
[[1,3],[24,1]],
[[17,1],[3,2]],
[[21,2],[23,0]],
[[10,3],[15,0]],
[[9,1],[16,0]],
[[5,1],[2,0]],
[[22,2],[13,1]],
[[24,1],[18,0]],
[[20,0],[19,1]],
[[14,0],[12,2]],
[[11,2],[4,0]],
[[8,3],[7,0]],
[[1,4],[6,1]],
[[2,1],[10,4]],
[[6,1],[8,1]],
[[12,0],[22,3]],
[[4,2],[17,0]],
[[3,2],[20,3]],
[[7,1],[14,1]],
[[13,2],[1,0]],
[[16,1],[5,3]],
[[23,2],[11,3]],
[[15,0],[24,4]],
[[19,3],[9,1]],
[[18,0],[21,3]],
[[5,1],[6,1]],
[[21,0],[4,1]],
[[20,1],[7,3]],
[[9,3],[23,0]],
[[24,0],[12,0]],
[[22,3],[18,0]],
[[17,1],[15,1]],
[[14,6],[13,2]],
[[11,2],[19,1]],
[[10,1],[3,0]],
[[8,4],[2,3]],
[[1,0],[16,0]],
[[13,0],[10,2]],
[[23,2],[24,2]],
[[12,3],[17,0]],
[[7,0],[9,0]],
[[6,2],[20,2]],
[[2,1],[21,3]],
[[18,1],[11,1]],
[[3,4],[14,1]],
[[19,0],[8,1]],
[[16,1],[22,1]],
[[15,2],[1,1]],
[[4,3],[5,2]],
[[12,0],[9,3]],
[[4,2],[22,0]],
[[3,0],[24,0]],
[[2,2],[11,1]],
[[6,2],[17,0]],
[[18,0],[8,1]],
[[13,1],[20,0]],
[[16,1],[21,3]],
[[23,2],[1,0]],
[[15,2],[14,1]],
[[19,1],[10,4]],
[[7,1],[5,1]],
[[14,3],[2,0]],
[[8,3],[4,2]],
[[9,0],[18,0]],
[[10,0],[7,1]],
[[11,0],[16,2]],
[[5,3],[23,3]],
[[17,2],[13,1]],
[[24,1],[6,2]],
[[20,0],[15,2]],
[[21,5],[19,0]],
[[22,1],[3,2]],
[[1,1],[12,1]],
[[23,0],[2,1]],
[[8,3],[9,4]],
[[1,2],[14,1]],
[[4,2],[18,1]],
[[5,0],[21,0]],
[[6,0],[13,4]],
[[15,2],[22,1]],
[[12,1],[20,0]],
[[17,1],[10,2]],
[[19,2],[16,1]],
[[24,4],[11,2]],
[[7,1],[3,1]],
[[13,3],[12,1]],
[[11,1],[6,1]],
[[3,0],[1,2]],
[[2,1],[7,2]],
[[10,2],[4,1]],
[[21,2],[17,1]],
[[16,0],[8,1]],
[[20,1],[23,0]],
[[22,1],[5,1]],
[[18,0],[15,1]],
[[14,1],[19,2]],
[[9,1],[24,1]],
[[12,0],[3,1]],
[[1,1],[9,0]],
[[4,1],[16,2]],
[[7,4],[18,2]],
[[8,2],[20,0]],
[[6,0],[10,1]],
[[15,2],[21,1]],
[[19,4],[13,4]],
[[23,0],[14,0]],
[[24,3],[22,2]],
[[17,2],[2,2]],
[[5,3],[11,0]],
[[21,1],[8,2]],
[[9,2],[4,2]],
[[10,2],[5,1]],
[[2,2],[24,1]],
[[23,4],[16,0]],
[[22,1],[1,1]],
[[20,4],[17,1]],
[[14,3],[6,1]],
[[13,2],[7,1]],
[[11,0],[12,1]],
[[3,1],[15,1]],
[[18,1],[19,2]]
]
```

### Shorter examples

All are given as `[[first team, first team score],[second team, second team score]]` but this order can be transposed if preferred.

```
[[1,1],[2,1]],[[2,2],[1,0]] -> 2,1
[[1,2],[2,3]],[[1,2],[3,2]],[[1,3],[4,1]],[[1,2],[5,1]],[[2,2],[3,4]],[[2,4],[4,2]],[[2,2],[5,2]],[[3,4],[4,2]],[[3,3],[5,2]],[[4,4],[5,2]],[[2,4],[1,2]],[[3,3],[1,3]],[[4,2],[1,3]],[[5,1],[1,2]],[[3,3],[2,3]],[[4,2],[2,3]],[[5,3],[2,1]],[[4,3],[3,1]],[[5,3],[3,2]],[[5,1],[4,3]] -> 2,1,3,4,5
[[1,3],[2,4]],[[1,3],[3,3]],[[2,0],[3,2]],[[2,3],[1,1]],[[3,4],[1,0]],[[3,3],[2,2]] -> 3,2,1
[[1,3],[2,2]],[[1,3],[3,1]],[[1,4],[4,0]],[[2,2],[3,2]],[[2,3],[4,3]],[[3,2],[4,1]],[[2,3],[1,2]],[[3,3],[1,4]],[[4,2],[1,2]],[[3,4],[2,1]],[[4,2],[2,2]],[[4,4],[3,2]] -> 1,3,2,4
[[1,0],[2,2]],[[1,2],[3,0]],[[1,2],[4,0]],[[2,1],[3,2]],[[2,2],[4,4]],[[3,3],[4,2]],[[2,4],[1,3]],[[3,2],[1,2]],[[4,3],[1,2]],[[3,2],[2,3]],[[4,2],[2,2]],[[4,4],[3,2]] -> 4,2,1,3
```

### Questions

1. The hardest bit seems to be checking head to head record. That’s in the rules, but does it over-complicate things?
2. Are the examples, particularly the real-world one, too long?

Answer (score 0):

## [The TAK function (easy mode)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269684/78410)

Answer (score 0):

## How many ways does this string conform to this expression?

Given an expression, decide in how many ways could an inputted string consisting of only printable ascii conforms to that expression. The best way to explain how the expression works is with an example, so here is one.

Let's say the expression is `a + b + c + a`. That means the string should start with a contiguous substring a, then at some point split into substring b, and finally end with substring a again (is this example, a, b, and c must be distinct.) Now let's say the string is "hello world please subscribe hello". One possible way would be:

```
a = "hello"
b = " world "
c = " please subscribe "
```

You task is to find how many ways you can split up the string so that the resulting substrings conform to the expression. If no split exists, output/return 0.

[more coming soon]

Answer (score 0):

## Tile the untileable

Only triangles, squares, and hexagons can tile perfectly with no gaps. With any other polygon, there will always be gaps. But what if you could tile with say, a pentagon? You just have to cheat, with other shapes. Given two integers a and b, how many x-sided polygons where a != x and x >= 3 are needed so that you can tile b a-sided polygons perfectly with the help of x-sided polygons? You may assume it is always possible.

### More constraints

- The area and perimeter of all a-sided polygons must be equal
- ^ must also hold for the n x-sided polygons

[example and test cases coming soon]

---

- I don't know how to do this at all.
- The wording could probably be better.

Comment: "Only triangles, squares, and hexagons can tile perfectly with no gaps" You should have the word "regular" somewhere, otherwise this is wrong and sort of confusing.  It's overall not clear to me what polygons are assumed to be regular in this question.

Answer (score 0):

## [Solve a squared cryptarithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269592/91472)

Answer (score 0):

## Summarise a Long Conversation

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [prompt-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-golf)

---

*Note: I'm aware that there's been some attempts at doing chatgpt golf on the site but there's always been the problem of subjectivity. I've come up with an idea that could maybe add objectivity to the concept of general LLM golfing*

*Second note: prompt golf doesn't exist as a tag yet so it'd be created upon question posting most likely if at all*

*Final note: this might be better as a meta discussion, but just to kick things off I've made it a sandbox post*

---

*Inspired by a real life problem*

If you ever been in a busy SE chat room/discord server/whatsapp group chat or any other place where you can talk over the internet and there's lots of messages, you'll know that it can be hard to keep up with what's being discussed. Especially if you've been away for a while (e.g sleep) and there's literal hundreds of new messages.

Your task today is to take a list of messages and summarise it into a nice digestible format.

"But that's a hard problem people have spent years researching and everything like how do you expect us to write a summarisation algorithm that's actually good without using something like a LLM?"

By using a LLM, obviously.

### Challenge

Given a series of messages with each individual message on a new line, write a prompt that summarises the content.

To verify that the output is actually a summary, the result will be run by an oracle prompt in <insert LLM that'll be used for testing>:

```
<prompt I've yet to write that outputs either yes or no depending on whether the oracle LLM would summarise in the same way>
```

To account for the non-deterministic behaviour of LLMs (their temperature), your prompt must return an accepted result for at least 4 out of 5 runs. *required run rate subject to change*. This is to establish that it's a genuinely working prompt and not a fluke.

Alternatively, if your LLM has a temperature setting you can set to 0, or is deterministic by default only one verified run is needed.

### Input Format

```
name: message
name: message
```

### Rules

*to be finalised - I might decide to switch up how this challenge is scored*

- Inputs will not be longer than 1000 characters (to ensure no token limits are reached)
- Prompts that try to return results that jailbreak the oracle are allowed, but note that you'll probably find better results by just doing the task legitimately.
- LLMs you can use are Chatgpt 3.5/ 4 and Google Bard.
- provide links to sample runs if possible.
- The answer(s) with the shortest prompt as measured in utf-8 bytes wins.

### Example Inputs

*todo*

### Sandbox meta

- Does this work towards solving the subjectivity problem of prompt golf?
- Does the testing/verification method need more runs or a different set-up?
- Is prompt golf even something that should be a challenge?
- Are there any other things I haven't thought of?

Comment: So basically, you are given a transcript and give a prompt to an LLM to summarize the transcript, right? How do you compare how good summarizations are?

Comment: @AlanBreadel that's what the Oracle LLM is for. It's used to determine whether an output is valid.

Comment: How do you make sure the Oracle LLM isn't biased? (for example the oracle gives a higher score to prompts that praise it)

Answer (score 0):

## [Modular Equivalence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269712/modular-equivalence)

Answer (score 0):

[3D Hide & Seek Word Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269752/3d-hide-seek-word-puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

**bit-packing**

The GSM7 03.38 protocol specifies a bit packing/unpacking algorithm, to pack septets into octets and vice-versa.

The following https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/470755/Encoding-Decoding-7-bit-User-Data-for-SMS-PDU-PDU is a reasonable reference implementation, which details the packing algorithm.

**challenge**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the packing algorithm - shortest code wins.

**input**

byte array in a style relevant to your language

**output**

packed byte array

You can use http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288 to check your work - enter some text at the top, click convert, convert again, and then "User data translation (7 bit only)" for a handy comparison chart between the octets and septets.

Answer (score 0):

## State compression

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

A long time ago in a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/124145) <sup>far, far away</sup>, golfers were tasked with outputting one of three different outputs, depending on whether the input was: `OR`, one of the other 49 American states' two-letter abbreviations, or something else entirely. The list of these letter pairs looks like this:

```
AL, AK, AZ, AR, CA, CO, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, ID, IL, IN, IA, KS, KY, LA, ME, MD, MA, MI, MN, MS, MO, MT, NE, NV, NH, NJ, NM, NY, NC, ND, OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, SD, TN, TX, UT, VT, VA, WA, WV, WI, WY
```

The standard approach to achieve the task was to search for the input in this string, bar the commas but *not* the spaces. If the spaces were to be removed, unintended letter pairs would appear within the string. For example, this string would start with `ALAKAZ` and while the newly formed `LA` is one of the valid pairs (and hence, did not need to appear again in the search string), the same cannot be said for `KA`. (And you'd probably anger some people from Kansas. I dunno, I've no idea what people from Kansas get up to.)

But, with some careful rearrangement, the technique could be used in certain places to save a handful of bytes. The string that most solutions ended up using looked like this:

```
MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY
```

Pretty unrecognizable, right? If you look at the first "word", `MINCALA`, it contains `MI`, `IN`, `NC`, `CA`, `AL`, and `LA`, which are all valid pairs. But if you were to remove the space after it, then you would end up with `AM`, which is *not* a valid pair.

Thing is though, I'm still not entirely certain this string is optimal, which is why I'm asking you to...

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes a **list of strings** of uniform length and outputs the **shortest list of combinations** that, when combined into a string with some delimiter, contains all the input strings, but no other string of the same length without that delimiter.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be  **scored in bytes**, unless otherwise specified.
- Built-in functions that achieve this (now that's *unlikely*) are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

> Yet to come.

[This challenge was sandboxed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26269)

---

## Sandbox

- This title still *sucks*.

Comment: Is it allowed for a string to appear multiple times in the search string? I'm not sure how this could work with nonuniform lengths. What do you mean by a [tag:decision-problem]? Testing if a given search string is valid? This seems very different, and IMO this question is more interesting.

Comment: @CommandMaster I'm not against strings appearing multiple times in the output inherently but I don't know if that can happen in the optimal output. As for the kind of challenge it is, I have decided it'll be a [tag:code-golf].

Comment: A typical solution may works in \$O((n+1)!k)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of candidate strings and \$k\$ is the size of strings. As the result, it could probably cannot handle any large testcases.

Comment: Maybe testcase "EAB ABC BCA CAB BCE" -> "EABCABCE" use "ABC" twice

Answer (score 0):

[Solve a logic puzzle by exhaustively applying three rules to rows and columns of a table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269769/120970)

Comment: @noodleman Thanks for your feedback on my original post. Are the examples in this post clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

[Alternating Random Series Sum To \$N\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269789/alternating-random-series-sum-to-n)

Answer (score 0):

## [Counting rankings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/269850/78410)

Answer (score 0):

[Generate a sequence of \$n\$ consecutive composite numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269810/generate-a-sequence-of-n-consecutive-composite-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

[TYPOGLYCEMIA - Cna Yuo Raed Tihs?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269918/typoglycemia-cna-yuo-raed-tihs)

Answer (score 0):

## NDos' Well-Temperament [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [music](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)

### Objective

Given a **positive** integer \$n\$, output the ratios in the **NDos' well-temperament** with \$n\$ notes, as defined below.

### NDos' well-temperament

NDos' well-temperament (abbr. **NWT**) is a musical temperament whose every step is a superparticular ratio. A ratio is **superparticular** if it equals \$\frac{n+1}{n}\$ for some positive integer \$n\$.

By being octave-periodic, NWT with \$n\$ notes is essentially a multiplicative partition of the rational number \$2\$ with \$n\$ entries.

There is one restriction that ensures NWT to exist uniquely. Amongst such multiplicative partitions, NWT is the partition that comes the *last* **co-lexicographically** (That is, the last ratio must be the biggest as possible, the second-to-last ratio is a tiebreaker, the third-to-last ratio is another tiebreaker, and so on) when the ratios are sorted in *descending* order.

### I/O format

Flexible. In particular, since the outputted list consists of superparticular ratios, you can output their denominators only, or output their numerators only. Note that, by doing this, NWT becomes the *first* partition in co-lexicographic order when the denominators (or the numerators) are sorted in *ascending* order.

### Notes

Musically, NWT will sound better if its ratios are rearranged in a particular way. This challenge won't ask to rearrange them.

### Examples

Only denominators are shown for the ratios.

```
Input, Output
1, [1]
2, [2,3]
3, [3,4,5]
4, [4,5,6,7]
5, [6,6,7,7,8]
6, [6,7,8,9,10,11]
7, [8,9,9,10,10,11,11]
8, [9,10,10,11,11,12,13,14]
9, [10,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15]
10, [12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,17]
11, [12,13,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,19]
12, [15,15,16,16,16,17,17,17,18,18,19,19]
```

### Ungolfed solution (Haskell)

This particular implementation is quite slow upon bigger inputs. Haven't analyzed the time complexity exactly, but I doubt this runs in polynomial time.

```
import Data.List

colex :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
colex [] [] = EQ
colex [] _  = LT
colex _  [] = GT
colex (x:xs) (y:ys) = colex xs ys <> compare x y

ndosWT :: Int -> [Int]
ndosWT = go [1] where
    go :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
    go [] _ = []
    go [x] 1 = [x]
    go [x] n = minimumBy colex $ do
        m <- [2 .. n]
        let ys = take m [m*x ..]
        pure (go ys n)
    go xs@(x:xs1) n = case compare n (length xs) of
        LT -> []
        EQ -> xs
        _  -> minimumBy colex $ do
            m <- [quot (n + (length xs - 1)) (length xs) .. n - (length xs - 1)]
            pure (sort (go [x] m ++ go xs1 (n-m)))
```

Optimized version:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

colex :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
colex [] [] = EQ
colex [] _  = LT
colex _  [] = GT
colex (x:xs) (y:ys) = colex xs ys <> compare x y

ndosWT :: Int -> [Int]
ndosWT n = fromJust (go [1] n)
  where
    threshold :: Int
    threshold = 2 * n

    colex_maybe_min :: Ord a => Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
    colex_maybe_min Nothing mys = mys
    colex_maybe_min mxs Nothing = mxs
    colex_maybe_min (Just xs) (Just ys) = if GT == colex xs ys
        then Just ys
        else Just xs

    weave :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    weave [] ys = ys
    weave xs [] = xs
    weave xs@(x:xs1) ys@(y:ys1) = if x <= y
        then x : weave xs1 ys
        else y : weave xs ys1

    go :: [Int] -> Int -> Maybe [Int]
    go [] _ = Nothing
    go [x] 1 = if x < threshold
        then Nothing
        else Just [x]
    go [x] n = foldr1 colex_maybe_min $ do
        m <- [2 .. n]
        let ys = take m [m*x ..]
        pure $ if last ys < threshold
            then go ys n
            else Nothing
    go xs@(x:xs1) n = case compare n (length xs) of
        LT -> Nothing
        EQ -> Just xs
        _  -> foldr1 colex_maybe_min $ do
            m <- [quot (n + (length xs - 1)) (length xs) .. n - (length xs - 1)]
            pure (fmap (\[xs, ys] -> weave xs ys) (sequence [go [x] m, go xs1 (n-m)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are way too few proof golf challenges for my taste, so I'd like to introduce a permanent one.

- Is it too long or complicated?
- My data is a work in progress, so there is still time before this challenge could potentially be ready.

---

## The hardest logic puzzle game: Help me reduce my oversized proofs!

I put a lot of work into finding small proofs that elevate smallest-known single axioms to more practical (and popular) proof systems. Some are still large, can you find better proofs based on my data?

This [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf) challenge is all about finding some shorter proof(s) based on existing ones. The problems are similar to [[CG question: (A → B) → (¬B → ¬A)]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161172), but based on different [Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system), and vary in how to display and measure proofs.<sup>✻</sup> It also leaves much more choice on what to solve to the contestant. All parts are interconnected and might lead to improve each other. Choosing wisely which of the given pieces to tackle is part of the challenge!

For the sake of this logic challenge, the length of [condensed detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_detachment) proofs in a certain prefix notation (so-called *D-proofs*) serves to measure the quality of solutions. The shorter the better!

<sup>✻</sup><sub>Note that we use the same metric to measure proofs as in the reference of the [best answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170881) to the aforementioned question, in contrast to the amount of formulas that occur in a proof. So looking for multiple occurrences of a formula in the same proof and reducing by referencing only one of them is intentionally not a part of this.</sub>

### Tournament Rules

<sup>All of the following rules are subject to be refined based on experience gained over time.</sup>

###### Rewards

This is an *infinite* challenge (up until I die and nobody maintains it anymore or I edit the question accordingly – planned: never). I will reward all my reputation points gathered here, down to 101, to best answers, provided they improve by at least 50 steps in total (for 50 points) w.r.t. to the previously given best answer (or my data if there is none), with points up to the number of improved steps (but capped at the maximum bounty of 500 points per solution).
Once an improvement is confirmed, I will start the according bounty and award it as soon as possible.
Since I consider this question to be very challenging, I do not expect there to be many best answers in small time frames, but if that happens, I'll schedule the bounties according to timestamps of answers, and put in up to whichever spare reputation points are available when starting the bounty.
(If I do not react in reasonable time due to being absent here, you may comment in the [discussions forum](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator/discussions) related to my project that this question arose from. This will drop me an email.)

There are no plans of using the *accepted answer* feature. This is in order to not give newcomers the false impression that this challenge has somehow already been ”solved”.
I consider each improvement quite the accomplishment, so I will of course upvote each improving answer, as soon as I found and verified it.

If this endless riddle fascinates you as well and you have spare reputation points (unlike me, at the time of writing this), feel free to contact me and/or edit this section on how you would like to contribute to these rewards.

Regardless, I would very much apprechiate if you could upvote this question so that I am able to reward deserving participants.

###### Challenge

There are seven theorems to prove in seven similar proof systems. The challenge is to minimize the proofs as much as possible. You may pick any number of theorems to prove in any of these systems, so there can be at most 49 evaluated proofs per solution.
Each combination varies in difficulty, and I will state a subjectively perceived difficulty (range 1 to 10) for each system. In the hardest system (called w2), three proofs are still missing (i.e. finding a proof is worth infinitely many steps regardless of its length<sup>✻</sup>). I initially provide D-proofs for all other combinations.<sup>❈</sup>

Some proofs are so long that surely there must be shorter ones, but several are already minimal or likely close to minimal, which can be seen by the number of steps covered by an exhaustive search, which I will also provide.

<sup>✻</sup><sub>To avoid infinite scoring loopholes, I may treat all subproofs of intermediate theorems to be at most as long as previously shortest-known such proofs.</sub>
<sup>❈</sup><sub>These proofs and my data are to be used as valuable hints. Starting from scratch would be way too hard, encourage terrible solutions, and break the unlimited scoring system.</sub>

###### Scoring

The score is the number of improved steps. As such it is always relative to the last best solution (which initially I provide). There are no negative scores: If you state a proof longer than a previously known proof, it will be worth 0 points.

For example, say there are two challengers A and B starting based on my data. Now challenger A improves proofs X and Y by 42 and 120 steps, respectively, and challenger B afterwards improves proofs Y and Z (≠ X) by 52 and 330 steps, respectively.
Then first A receives a reward of up to 150 reputation points (which is the closest multiple of 50 that is at most 162 = 42 + 120). B improved by 340 = 10 + 330 = (52 - 42) + 330 steps relative to the previously shortest-known proofs, thus receives a reward of up to 300 points.
Further assume that I only have 301 (thus 200 spare) reputation points when rewarding A, then A receives the full 150 points, leaving me at only 50 (above 101) left. Afterwards, B receives those 50 points together with those which I acquired in the meantime (multiples of 50, still capped at 300).

Note that there are not only timestamps but also increasing answer IDs to determine sequence of answers, so there can never be a tie in which answer came first. The answer ID acts as a tiebreaker for edits (which could potentially occur in the same second).

###### Answers

Answers should somehow provide an abstract representation similar to the one I provide, unless a D-proof is short enough to be stated in full (at most a few thousand characters), in which case it can be stated concretely.<sup>✻</sup> Of course, you can additionally provide the proof in whichever representation you like, e.g. with all used logical formulas, in infix notation, etc.
An explanation on how you succeeded and where you failed would be nice, but is not required.

Only one (the first) answer per user is taken into account, but a proof-shortening edit is treated and scored like a new contribution at the time of editing. When there are multiple edits with multiple improvements, only the last edit is rewarded.<sup>❈</sup>

Improvements can be summarized in the title like “(<system>:<theorem>:<steps before>-><steps after>, ...)”, e.g. “(w2:A3:9001->1337, w4:id:465->379)”. However, the scoring will follow a procedure independent from such statements, and I might comment and/or request to edit relevant scoring information.

In case you would like to be mentioned by name (or pseudonym) for your contribution in my [corresponding project](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator) and potential publications, please state so in your answer or via [forum or email](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator/discussions), and how. By default, I will use your username on Code Golf Stack Exchange.

<sup>✻</sup><sub>You may even do some conventional code golfing to print your solution with as little code as possible. This may grant you upvotes, but no extra tournament points.</sub>
<sup>❈</sup><sub>But in case your answer has already been rewarded and you find a further improvement, you can edit your answer and receive another reward – after dropping me a message so that I notice your edit. If there was no message and another answer received the corresponding reward due to your edit being unnoticed, your reward is lost (to another person).</sub>

###### Winning

Apart from the relative score, I'd like to treat this like a global game for which one can lead a “highscore” (but with lower numbers being better).
Starting with three proofs unknown, the initial value is `3ω+c`, where `c` is the sum of steps of smallest-known proofs, one for each solved target theorem.
The game becomes even harder once it progresses, but latest successes automatically grant a top ranking. For that, I'll maintain a table below.

I have hopes that it will someday reach a finite amount close to several thousand steps. It seems plausible that this is possible when looking at high exponential growths in the amounts of theorems when doing exhaustive generations. Quantum computers might help a lot in the forseeable future.

One could say that somebody won this competition, when no other individual is able to find any shorter proofs anymore. But due to the complexity of the problem, this might as well take billions of years.
I would guess that there are some alien races doing the same thing: After all, this concerns a few very special systems – all minimal 1-bases for {→,¬}‑propositional calculus.

### Hall of Fame

|  | Competitor | Total Steps | Date | Recent Improvements |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | [xamidi](https://github.com/xamidi) ([profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/114913)) | 3ω+20869754 | Feb 03, 2024 | initial proofs |

Consecutive entries of the same user will be combined. Please let me know what you wish to be called or whether to link to a different site than only your Code Golf user profile.

### Proof Systems

We are exploring the seven minimal 1-bases for classical propositional logic that use operators → (read: “implies”) and ¬ (read: “not”) with [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) (⊢ψ,⊢ψ→φ ⇒ ⊢φ, sometimes called “detachment”)<sup>✻</sup> as a rule of inference.

<sup>✻</sup><sub>This rule can be read as “if (the proposition) ψ is provable and (the proposition) ψ→φ is provable, then thereby (the proposition) φ is provable”.
An operator '⊢' for ”is provable” is not part of the propositional language. Propositions merely argue about truth, using '→', '¬', and other propositions.
For example, the formula ψ→φ can be read as ”if (the proposition) ψ is true, then (the proposition) φ is true”. Suppose ψ→φ is true. When also ”(the proposition) ψ is true”, it follows via modus ponens that ”(the proposition) φ is true”. This kind of argument is the only one allowed in our proofs. Variables (such as ψ and φ) can be *instantiated* with arbitrary propositions (i.e. formulas in our propositional language).</sub>

###### Axioms

The axioms of our systems are [Meredith's axiom](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/meredith.html) and [Walsh's six axioms](http://fitelson.org/walsh.pdf). These can be stated in our propositional language as follows.

|  | Infix notation | Polish notation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [m](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/meredith.svg) | [((((ψ→φ)→(¬χ→¬ξ))→χ)→τ)→((τ→ψ)→(ξ→ψ))](https://truth-table.com/#((((a%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92(%C2%ACc%E2%86%92%C2%ACd))%E2%86%92c)%E2%86%92e)%E2%86%92((e%E2%86%92a)%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92a))) | `CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp` |
| [w1](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh1st.svg) | [(ψ→((¬ψ→φ)→χ))→(ξ→((¬τ→(χ→τ))→(ψ→τ)))](https://truth-table.com/#(a%E2%86%92((%C2%ACa%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92c))%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92((%C2%ACe%E2%86%92(c%E2%86%92e))%E2%86%92(a%E2%86%92e)))) | `CCpCCNpqrCsCCNtCrtCpt` |
| [w2](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh2nd.svg) | [ψ→((φ→(ψ→χ))→((¬χ→((¬ξ→τ)→φ))→(ξ→χ)))](https://truth-table.com/#a%E2%86%92((b%E2%86%92(a%E2%86%92c))%E2%86%92((%C2%ACc%E2%86%92((%C2%ACd%E2%86%92e)%E2%86%92b))%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92c)))) | `CpCCqCprCCNrCCNstqCsr` |
| [w3](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh3rd.svg) | [ψ→((¬φ→((¬χ→ξ)→(ψ→τ)))→((τ→φ)→(χ→φ)))](https://truth-table.com/#a%E2%86%92((%C2%ACb%E2%86%92((%C2%ACc%E2%86%92d)%E2%86%92(a%E2%86%92e)))%E2%86%92((e%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92(c%E2%86%92b)))) | `CpCCNqCCNrsCptCCtqCrq` |
| [w4](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh4th.svg) | [ψ→((¬φ→((¬χ→ξ)→(τ→φ)))→((χ→τ)→(χ→φ)))](https://truth-table.com/#a%E2%86%92((%C2%ACb%E2%86%92((%C2%ACc%E2%86%92d)%E2%86%92(e%E2%86%92b)))%E2%86%92((c%E2%86%92e)%E2%86%92(c%E2%86%92b)))) | `CpCCNqCCNrsCtqCCrtCrq` |
| [w5](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh5th.svg) | [(ψ→φ)→(((χ→(ξ→τ))→(φ→(¬ξ→¬ψ)))→(ψ→ξ))](https://truth-table.com/#(a%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92(((c%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92e))%E2%86%92(b%E2%86%92(%C2%ACd%E2%86%92%C2%ACa)))%E2%86%92(a%E2%86%92d))) | `CCpqCCCrCstCqCNsNpCps` |
| [w6](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/walsh6th.svg) | [((ψ→φ)→(((¬χ→¬ξ)→χ)→τ))→((τ→ψ)→(ξ→ψ))](https://truth-table.com/#((a%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92(((%C2%ACc%E2%86%92%C2%ACd)%E2%86%92c)%E2%86%92e))%E2%86%92((e%E2%86%92a)%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92a))) | `CCCpqCCCNrNsrtCCtpCsp` |

Different axioms are not allowed to be combined with each other. Indeed, each of these formulas is capable of deducing all theorems of propositional logic using only modus ponens as a rule of inference.

In order to save space, I will use standard Polish notation, a most concise (and well-googleable) prefix notation with (→,¬)=(`C`,`N`) for up to 26 different variables `p`,`q`,...,`z`,`a`,...,`o`, to state conclusions in proof summaries.
You may use whichever well-defined formula representation suits you. Actually, a formula is simply a tree structure – follow the links in the leftmost column for graphical representations.
A general way (which works for more than 26 different variables) to concisely state formulas is to use numbers as variables and separate them via `.`, e.g. `CCCCC0.1CN2N3.2.4CC4.0C3.0` for Meredith's axiom.

### Target Theorems

The target theorems are themselves axioms of [popular proof systems](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/pjab1945/41/6/41_6_436/_pdf), such as {A1,A2,A3} (“Łukasiewicz (L_3)-system”) and {L1,L2,L3} (“Łukasiewicz (L_1)-system”). Propositional axioms of Metamath's main proof database set**.**mm [are also A1-A3](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html#scaxioms).

|  | Infix notation | Polish notation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [A1](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/frege-1.svg) | ψ→(φ→ψ) | `CpCqp` |
| [A2](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/frege-2.svg) | (ψ→(φ→χ))→((ψ→φ)→(ψ→χ)) | `CCpCqrCCpqCpr` |
| [A3](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/svg/lukasiewicz-3.svg) | (¬ψ→¬φ)→(φ→ψ) | `CCNpNqCqp` |
| id | ψ→ψ | `Cpp` |
| L1 | (ψ→φ)→((φ→χ)→(ψ→χ)) | `CCpqCCqrCpr` |
| L2 | (¬ψ→ψ)→ψ | `CCNppp` |
| L3 | ψ→(¬ψ→φ) | `CpCNpq` |

Proving all axioms of a different proof system that is known to be [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)) (such as A1-A3 and L1-L3 both are under modus ponens) proves that the original system is complete by itself. There are also non-constructive ways to prove this, which is how we know that w2 is complete under modus ponens, despite such proofs still being unknown.<sup>✻</sup> The length of such proofs could help in finding proof theoretic bounds, which are still a big mystery in the field of [proof complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_complexity).

<sup>✻</sup><sub>The authors of [Walsh's paper](http://fitelson.org/walsh.pdf) called the task to find D-proofs from w2 to another system an “open challenge problem for automated reasoning”. Based on my data, it only remains to find a D-proof for L1. This is, however, by far the hardest optional part in this callenge, and I sure do not recommend it to anyone who does not wish to put an outstanding amount of effort into this.</sub>

### Proof Notation

The operator for condensed detachment is the so-called `D`-rule, which takes two formulas as arguments, on which it applies [tree unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) to form the *most general unifiers* of ψ→φ and ψ, respectively, then applies modus ponens, which results in φ. Axioms in D-proofs are referred to by `1`,`2`,…,`9`,`a`,`b`,…,`z` in their given order.

This way, given a sequence of axioms, a proof can be defined by a single prefix formula, e.g. `DD211`, which is evaluated like `D(D(2,1),1)`, i.e. `D` is a 2-ary (partially defined) operator over the language of logical formulas.
The `D`-rule is only partially defined because unifiers to apply modus ponens on certain formulas may not exist.

###### Example

Let's determine `DD211` for axioms (`1`,`2`):=(A1,A2). At first `D21` entails that ψ→φ and ψ are instances of A2 and A1, respectively. Most general such [unifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) are the instances (χ→(ξ→χ))→((χ→ξ)→(χ→χ)) and χ→(ξ→χ) of A2 and A1, which implies ψ := χ→(ξ→χ) and φ := (χ→ξ)→(χ→χ).
Therefore, (χ→ξ)→(χ→χ) (i.e. `CCpqCpp` in Polish notation) is an intermediate theorem in `DD211` = `D(CCpqCpp)1`. This entails that now ψ→φ and ψ are instances of (χ→ξ)→(χ→χ) and A1, respectively. Most general such unifiers are (χ→(τ→χ))→(χ→χ) and χ→(τ→χ), thus ψ := χ→(τ→χ) and φ := χ→χ.
Therefore, `DD211` proves the theorem χ→χ (i.e. `Cpp` in Polish notation). Combined, the D-proof `DD211` w.r.t. (A1,A2) actually means:

|  | Proposition | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | ψ→(φ→ψ) | (A1) |
| 2. | ψ→((φ→ψ)→ψ) | (A1) |
| 3. | (ψ→((φ→ψ)→ψ))→((ψ→(φ→ψ))→(ψ→ψ)) | (A2) |
| 4. | (ψ→(φ→ψ))→(ψ→ψ) | (MP):2,3 |
| 5. | ψ→ψ | (MP):1,4 |

Alternatively, using Polish notation:

1. `CpCqp` (`1`)
2. `CpCCqpp` (`1`)
3. `CCpCCqppCCpCqpCpp` (`2`)
4. `CCpCqpCpp` (`D`):2,3
5. `Cpp` (`D`):1,4

There are no such small examples in our single axiom systems, for example `D11` in Meredith's system is already

1. `CCCCCqsCNCNpNtNrCNpNtpCCpqCrq` (`1`)
2. `CCCCCCqsCNCNpNtNrCNpNtpCCpqCrqCCCCpqCrqCqsCtCqs` (`1`)
3. `CCCCpqCrqCqsCtCqs` (`D`):1,2

and formulas tend to blow up in size for longer proofs.
This illustrates that using formula-based proofs is extremely inefficient, whereas D-proofs are much lighter and can be processed by machines more efficiently.

### Challenge Proofs

<sup>I will try to keep this information up to date.</sup>

The smallest-known D-proofs of target theorems have the following amounts of steps.

|  | exhausted | A1 | A2 | A3 | id | L1 | L2 | L3 | overall difficulty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m | 83 (+2) | 13 | 7001 | 175 | 19 | 619 | 163 | 41 | not easy - 5/10 |
| w1 | 161 (+2) | 33 | 1927 | 363 | 143 | 151 | 323 | 87 | not easy - 5/10 |
| w2 | 43 (+2) | 53 | - | - | 35 | - | 781 | 57 | horrible - 10/10 |
| w3 | 73 (+2) | 67 | 18391835 | 1193987 | 135 | 1196969 | 6541 | 127 | very hard - 8/10 |
| w4 | 169 (+2) | 59 | 16277 | 12959 | 465 | 14261 | 1889 | 53 | bulky - 6/10 |
| w5 | 55 (+2) | 83 | 157 | 95 | 65 | 15 | 107 | 51 | convenient - 3/10 |
| w6 | 95 (+2) | 19 | 18339 | 297 | 13 | 2743 | 125 | 37 | not too bad - 4/10 |

For example, to the best of my knowledge I searched Meredith's system exhaustively for D-proofs of up to 83 steps. Since all its D-proofs have an odd length, all its smallest-known D-proofs with up to 85 steps are thereby minimal and cannot be reduced further. That is, if my search was actually exhaustive.

My (subjective) overall difficulty rating accounts for how hard I find searching and handling proofs, not for the apparent complexity of a system (which is indicated by “exhausted” – the higher the longer proofs are on average).
The issue with a lower difficulty rating is that the given proofs might be so short already that it is very hard to find a smaller one (if it even exists).
On the other hand, more difficult systems potentially give higher rewards.

Compact representations of these proofs are given below. Unfolding some of them results in exponential blowup, which explains the high number of steps asserted for concrete D-proofs.
Index numbers of target theorems are highlighted as **bold**. More detailed and commented variants representing the same D-proofs are linked over the system names right to the bullet points (and as “[sample]” in my project's [readme](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/README.html#custom-proof-systems)).

###### Puzzle Board (Abstract Representation)

- [m](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/m.txt):

```
    CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp = 1
[0] CCCppqCrq = D1D1D11
[1] CpCqp = DDD11[0]1
[2] CCCpqrCqr = D1D1D[0][0]
[3] Cpp = DDD[0][0]11
[4] CpCNpq = DD1[2][2]
[5] CCCpNCCCqrCNNqrNstCst = D1D1D[0]D1DD11DDDD1D1DD1DD11[0]111D1DD1D1D[1]D1D111
[6] CCpCpqCrCpq = DDD1D1D1D[0][5]11
[7] CCCpCqNCCrCNNssNqtCut = D1D1DD1DD1DDD1D1D[2]1D111D1D1D[0]D1DD11DDDD1D1DD1DD11[0]111D1DD1DD1D1D[0]1[1]D11DD1D11D11
[8] CCNppp = DD[6]DDD1D1DD1D1D[1]D1D11D[2]D[2]1111
[9] CCNpNqCqp = DDDDD1D1DD[2]1D[2]D[5]D1D1111DD1D1DD1D1D[2]1D11[1]1
[10] CCpqCCqrCpr = DD1DD1DDD[6][6]1[7]D1DDD[6][6]1[7]1
[11] CCpqCCrpCrq = DD[10]DD1DD1[7]1DD[6][6]1D[10][10]
[12] CCpCqrCCpqCpr = DD[11]D[10][10]DD[10][10]D[11]DD[6][6]1
```

- [w1](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w1.txt):

```
    CCpCCNpqrCsCCNtCrtCpt = 1
[0] CCNpCCqrpCrp = DD1D1D111
[1] CCCCpCCNpqrstCst = D[0]D1D11
[2] CCCpqrCqr = D[0]D1D1D11
[3] CpCCNqCrqCrq = D1D[2]D[0]D11
[4] CpCCNqCCNrsqCrq = D1DDDD[2]111D1D1D11
[5] CpCqp = D[2][1]
[6] CpCNpq = DD[0][4]D[0][3]
[7] CCCCNNpCpNpqrCpr = D[0]D1D[1]D[1]DD[0]D11DD[0]D11[2]
[8] CCNpCqpCrCCNsCpsCqs = DD[0]DD[2]1DDD1DDD[1]1D1111D1DDD[1]1D111D[2]1
[9] Cpp = DD[4]1D[7][2]
[10] CCpqCCqrCpr = D[2]DD[0]D1[8][2]
[11] CCCCpqCrqsCCrps = D[0]DD[2]1DD[0]D1DDD[1]1D1D1D111[10]
[12] CCCCNpCqpprCqr = D[0]D1DD[0]D1D[1]D[1]1DD[0]D11D[0]DD[1]D[1]1D[7]D[0]DD[2]1[5]
[13] CCNppp = D[0]D[12]D[0][3]
[14] CCNpNqCqp = DD[2]DD1DD[0]D1D[2][8]D[0]DD[2]D[1]D[2]1D[7][2]1D[4]1
[15] CCpCqrCCpqCpr = DD[11]D[0]D1DD[0]D1D[1]D[2]1DD[0]DD[2]1DD[0]D1DDD[1]1D111[2]DD[0]D11D[0]DD[1]D[2]1D[7]D[0]DD[2]1[5]D[11]DDD[3]1DD[0]DDD1D111DD[0]D1DDDD[1]D[2]1D[1]D[2]DD[0]D11[6]1D1DDD[1]1D1D1D111D[2]D[2]DD[0][4]1D[12][2]DD[0]DDD1D111DD[0]DD[2]1D[0]D1DD[0]D1D[1]D[2]1DDDD[2]1D[0]DD[2]1DD[3]1DD[0][4]D[0]D1DDD[1]1D1111D11DD[0][4]1D[1]D[1]DD[0]D1DD[0]DD[1]1DD[0]D1DD[0]D1DDD[1]1D1111[2]1[2]
```

- [w2](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w2.txt):   (missing: `CCNpNqCqp`,`CCpCqrCCpqCpr`,`CCpqCCqrCpr`)

```
    CpCCqCprCCNrCCNstqCsr = 1
[0] CpCCNqCCNrsCNqCCNCCNtCCNuvNpCutwNCxCCyCxzCCNzCCNabyCazCrq = DDDDD111111
[1] Cpp = DDD11DDD11D11[0][0]
[2] CpCqCrCsCtq = DDDDD1DDD11DD1D111[0]1[0]11
[3] CpCqp = DDD1D[2]1D111
[4] CpCNpq = DDDDD1D111[0]DDD11DDD1D111[0][0]1
[5] CpCqCrp = DDD11DD11DDD1D111[0][2]
[6] CCNppp = DDDDD1[1]1DDDD11DDD1[5]D11DDD11DDD1D111[0]1DDD1DDDD11D1DD1DDD1[0]D1111[0]DDD11D1[0][0]DDD1D1D[2]11[0]DDDDD11111[0]1DDDD11[5]DDD1DDD11D1DDD11DDD1D111[0]1DDD11DDD1DDD1DD1D111111[0]1DDD1DDD1DDD1DDD1[0]D1111[0]1[0]1[0]DDDDD11111[0]1DDD1DDDDD1D111[0]DDD11DDD1D111[0][0]DDD11DDD1111DDD11DDD1DDD1DDD11D11[0]111[0]1D1[1]DDDD11D11[0]DD1[3]1
```

- [w3](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w3.txt):

```
    CpCCNqCCNrsCptCCtqCrq = 1
[0] CCCpCCqrCsrtCCCqrCsrt = DD1D111
[1] CCCpCqrsCCqrs = DD1DDDD111D[0]D11D111
[2] CCCpqrCqr = DDDDD[1]D111D[0]DD1111D11
[3] CCCNpqrCpr = DD11DDDDD111D[0]D11D1D11[1]
[4] CCNpCCNqrCCCCCCstuCtuvCCvwCxwyCCypCqp = D1DDD1[0]1D[0]DDDD[1]D11111
[5] CCNppCqp = DD11D[3]D11
[6] CpCqp = DDDDD[1]D111DD[1]D11111
[7] CpCCpqCrq = DDD1D11DDD[0]D[0]D1D[0]D1D11[0][1]D11
[8] CpCqCrp = D[2]D[1]DDDD111D[0]D11D11
[9] CCCNpqCCCCNrsCCtCutvCCvwCrwxCCxyCpy = D[1]D1D[1]D1[6]
[10] CCCCCpqrCsrtCqt = DD[1]DD[0]D[1]1[5]1
[11] CpCNpq = D[3]DD[0]D11[5]
[12] CCCpCqrsCrs = DD1[5]DDD[0]D[0]D1D[0]D11DD1[0]1[1]
[13] Cpp = DD[3]DD11[7]1
[14] CpCNNCqrCsCqr = DDD11DDD[1]DD[0]111DD[0]D[0]D1D11[0]DD[1]D[0]D1D[1]D1[6]DDD11DDD[1]DD[0]111DD[0]D[0]D1D11[0]DD1D11DDD11DDDDD111D[0]D11D1D11DD11DDD[0]D[0]D1[0]DD1DD1111[1]DDD11DDD[0]D[0]D1DDD1[0]1[0][1][1]DDDD111D[0]D11D1D11
[15] CCNCCppNqrCqr = D[9]DD1[13]D[14][14]
[16] CCNNpqCpq = D[9]D[4]D[2]DD[9]D[4]D[15][8][8]
[17] CpCqCrNNp = D[16][8]
[18] CCpqCNNpq = D[9]D[4][17]
[19] CCNpqCNCrpq = D[9]D[4]D[18]D[2][17]
[20] CCNpqCNCrCspq = D[9]D[4]D[18]D[12][17]
[21] CCCpqCNprCsCNpr = D[4]DD[9]D[4]D[18]D[3][17]D[10]D[7]D[3][15]
[22] CCNppp = D[16]DD[5]DD[9]D[4]D[3][17][5]D[5]DD[9]D[4]D[3][17][5]
[23] CCpNCNppCqNCNpp = D[4]D[18]D[10]D[7]DDD1[13]DD[4]D[19][8][7][22]
[24] CNCpqCrCsp = DDDDD1[13]DD[4]D[19][8][7][16]DD[4]DD[9]D[4]D[18]D[3][17][8]D[18]D[4]D[19][8]D[20]DD[21]DDD11DDD[0]D[0]D1[0]DD1[0]1[1]DDDD111D[0]D11D1D11DD[21][21]D[21][21]
[25] CCpCpqCpq = DDD[4][24]D[4][24]DD[4][24]D[4][24]
[26] CCpqCNCprq = D[9]D[4]DD[25][21]D[16]D[2]D[1]D[1]DDDD111D[0]D11D11
[27] CCCpqrCNpr = D[9]D[4]D[26][17]
[28] CCpqCCNppq = DD[1]D1D1D11D[4]DD[9]DD[9]D[4]D[18]DD[9][23][8]D[27][23][8]
[29] CpCCpqq = DDD[25]D[4]D[19][24]DDD[1]DD[0]111D[0]D[0]D1D[0]D11DDD1[6]DD[4]D[19][8][7][25]
[30] CCpqCCNqpq = D[4]DDD[1][4]D[28]D[10][25][28]
[31] CCNpNqCqp = D[16]DD[25]D[4]D[19][24]DD[30]D[2]D[3][15]D[19]D[25]DD[9]D[4]D[3][17][20]
[32] CCpqCCqrCpr = DDD1[26]D[6]D[28][29]DD[28][12]D[20]1
[33] CCpCqrCqCpr = DD[32][32]D[32][29]
[34] CCpCqrCCpqCpr = D[33]DD[32][32]DDD[28][12]D[20]1DD[33]D[27][30]D[33]DD[32][32][27]
```

- [w4](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w4.txt):

```
    CpCCNqCCNrsCtqCCrtCrq = 1
[0] CpCCNqCCNrsCtqp = DDD1111
[1] CpCNCqrp = DDD111DDDD111D[0]11
[2] CCpCNqCCNrsCtqCpCCrtCrq = DD11D[1]1
[3] CCpqCpCCNrCCNstCurq = DD11D[1]D[0][0]
[4] CpCNpq = DDD11D[1][0]DDDD111D[0]11
[5] CpCqp = DDD111DDD11DDDD11D[1]DDD111D[0]1111
[6] CCpqCpCrq = DD11D[1]D[0][5]
[7] CCpNNqCpq = DD11DDD11D[1]D[3][0]DDDD111D[0]11
[8] CCpqCCrpCrq = D[2]D[6][0]
[9] CCpCqNqCpCqr = DD11D[1]D[0]DD11D[2]DDDD111DD111DDD11D[1]D[3][0]DDDD111D[0]11
[10] CCpqCpNNq = DD[2][3]D[9]DDD11D[1]D[0][7][5]
[11] Cpp = DDDDD[2]DD11D[1]D[0]D[3][5]D[6]DDD11D[1]D[0]DD11DDD11D[1]D[0]DD11D[1]D[0]DDD11D[1][0]DDDD111D1111DDD111D[1]1111
[12] CCNppp = D[7]DDD11DDD[2][3]D[1]D[6]D[9][5]DDD[2][3]D[9]DDDD11D[3]D[2]DDD11D[1]D[0]DD11D[1][4][1]DD1111DDDD11D[3]D[2]DDD11D[1]D[0]DD11D[1][4]DDD111D[1]1DD1111D[9][10]
[13] CpCCpqq = DDD[8][12]D[9]D[8]D[10][5]DDD[2][3]D[1]D[9][5]DDD[8][12]DD11D[1]D[0][4]DDD11D[1]D[0][6]DDD11D[3]DDD11D[1]D[0][4][5][11]
[14] CCNpNqCqp = DD[8]D[13][11]D[2]D[8][13]
[15] CCpqCCqrCpr = DDDD[8]D[13][11]D[2][3]DD[8][13]DDD11DDD11D[1]D[0]DDD11D[1]D[3][5]DDDD111D[0]11D[6]D[9][5][11]DDD11D[1]D[0][6][8]
[16] CCpCqrCCpqCpr = D[2]D[6]D[15][12]
```

- [w5](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w5.txt):

```
    CCpqCCCrCstCqCNsNpCps = 1
[0] CCpqCCqrCpr = DD11D1DD11D1D11
[1] CCCpCqrCCCsqtCNqNsCsq = DDD11DD1D11D1DD1D11DD11D1DD11D1DD1D1DD11D11D1D111
[2] CpCNpq = D[1]1
[3] Cpp = D[1][0]
[4] CpCqp = DDD11DDD11DDD11D11D1DDD11DD11D1DD11D1DD1D1DD11D11DD11D1DD11D1DD1D1DD11D11D1D111D111
[5] CCNpNqCqp = DD1DD11DD1D1DD1D1D1D11D1D11D1DD1D11D1D11D1D1[2]
[6] CCNppp = DD1[0]DD11D1DD11D1DDD11D1D1DD11D1D1DD11D1DD11D1DD1D1DD11DD1D1DD1D1D1D11D1D11D1DD1D11D1D11D11D11
[7] CCpCqrCCpqCpr = DDD11D1D11DD1DD11D1DDD11D1[1]DD11D1DD1D1DD11D1DD11D1DD1D11D11D1D11D1DD11D1D1DD11D1DD11D1DD1D11D1[0]
```

- [w6](https://xamidi.github.io/pmGenerator/data/w6.txt):

```
[...989 bytes in 19 lines ommitted to fit into the sandbox...]
```

### Where do I even start?

I called this a puzzle game for good reasons: Proofs for different theorems are components which can be used to build new components when arranged in a specific (and potentially very difficult to find) way. When it comes to snapping formulas together in order to create another one, things behave the same in all `D`-systems.

The above abstract proof representations hide many utilized formulas, but these can be viewed using [pmGenerator](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator) to display the “full summary” mentioned in the linked proof files – deriving them by hand is probably too much of a workload.
It may be useful, however, to write your own code to assist with this kind of work, and to follow your own ideas.

[...] (Does not fit into the sandbox.)

### Data & Tools

###### pmGenerator

[...]

###### Prover9

[...]

###### TPTP / Vampire

[...]

Comment: So, uh, I didn't really read this, but it looks long and complicated. Is there a small simpler part that you could split off into a self-contained bite-size challenge? It's common here to post an easier version as Part 1 and follow it up with a Part 2 later.

Comment: There are a few problems with splitting up, like big gaps in difficulty for different systems and theorems, and potential loss of focus for what is essentially a never-ending interconnected challenge. I am currently thinking that [Puzzling might be the better platform](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7542) for this.

Answer (score 0):

## Infinite monkeys with autocomplete

You've probably heard of the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem), which states that a monkey pressing keys on a keyboard at random will eventually type any possible string, the most well-known example being the complete works of Shakespeare. Of course, as the string grows longer and longer, the time taken to type that string becomes exponentially longer. But what if the monkey had an autocomplete?

Our hypothetical monkey starts with an alphabet, containing every possible character that it can type, and a dictionary that initially only contains every letter in the alphabet. At every step, it'll choose a random item from the dictionary and type it. But, the monkey has a helpful autocomplete guiding it to the correct string - if the last two items that were typed, concatenated, are a substring of the correct word that's not yet in the dictionary, it'll add that substring to the dictionary.

For example, let's start with the monkey trying to type the word `hello`, with the alphabet `helo`.

```
l o
```

It first types `l` and `o` and adds `lo` to the dictionary.

```
l o h lo l h e
```

It then types various random dictionary items before typing `h` and `e`, and adding `he` to the dictionary.

```
l o h lo l h e e e l
```

After some more random items, it types `e` and `l` and adds `l` to the dictionary.

```
l o h lo l h e e e l h lo o el e h el
```

Next, it types `h` and `el` and adds `hel`.

```
l o h lo l h e e e l h lo o el e h el lo
```

After typing the `el`, it types `lo` and adds `ello` to the dictionary.

```
l o h lo l h e e e l h lo o el e h el lo he hel he l o
```

Next, it types `he` and `l`, but because `hel` is already in the dictionary it's not added. For the same reason, `lo` is also not added.

```
l o h lo l h e e e l h lo o el e h el lo he hel he l o h ello
```

Finally, it types `h` and `ello`, creating `hello` after 24 attempts.

Your challenge is to, given a target word and alphabet containing only lowercase ASCII letters and spaces, simulate this behaviour, choosing random items and building up the dictionary until you eventually create the desired word. The alphabet will not contain any character more than once, and will at least contain every character in the target word.

At every step, you should choose a (not necessarily uniformly) random item from the dictionary, and the words you print should be separated by some consistent and unambigiuous delimiter. Although you do not have to uniformly randomly choose an item, it should be possible for any possible output sequence of strings to occur.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

#### Examples

Note that this is just one possible output for each input.

```
word = "abcba", alphabet = "abc" -> "a,a,c,b,b,cb,c,bcb,bcb,a,a,b,cb,ab,cb,b,bcba,bcba,c,b,cb,c,ab,bcba,c,bcb,ab,c,bcba,bcb,bcb,b,bcb,bcba,ab,a,b,a,c,cb,c,bcba,cb,abcb,abcb,ba,ba,abc,a,b,bcb,ab,bcb,a,ba,b,bcb,abc,c,abcb,a"
word = "hello", alphabet = "helo" -> "o,l,h,o,e,e,h,l,e,o,l,o,lo,lo,l,e,h,h,o,lo,h,l,lo,h,o,llo,o,llo,e,o,llo,lo,l,e,e,o,e,o,lo,l,l,ll,llo,h,l,ll,e,h,e,l,he,llo"
word = "hello", alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ->
"k,p,o,d,t,s,c,e,j,b,n,f,h,u,k,b,z,q,f,j,m,e,h,y,m,k,f,q,o,r,q,m,y,o,a,w,b,j,r,d,q,u,k,m,b,j,c,p,p,i,e,h,a,y,l,q,a,k,b,s,l,g,t,f,v,w,c,l,p,b,n,u,h,b,u,e,r,g,u,f,x,b,x,j,p,q,p,i,e,n,x,o,y,u,b,l,b,z,z,x,w,d,p,q,p,i,h,c,i,h,m,j,q,b,b,v,d,e,b,f,f,u,q,z,d,r,a,q,p,v,t,z,o,c,z,c,t,u,n,q,l,i,a,t,f,j,a,d,g,h,s,l,t,v,l,a,t,z,i,l,j,z,x,t,q,o,a,v,q,t,p,e,d,n,p,t,i,d,c,o,r,k,y,t,b,s,l,c,w,l,a,o,y,k,e,u,r,v,t,f,f,e,f,m,v,r,a,k,b,q,q,a,l,y,u,u,m,c,e,l,m,q,b,u,r,n,m,n,f,j,t,s,n,b,t,q,el,b,el,w,d,g,w,c,h,h,x,p,o,q,o,y,r,p,t,t,p,o,j,h,d,g,q,z,d,s,b,g,i,f,g,d,v,w,k,c,u,h,w,c,z,r,el,w,y,b,s,j,l,i,v,o,q,h,l,t,j,n,u,h,p,b,t,s,g,h,i,b,o,r,g,o,q,w,z,p,t,p,k,x,a,g,x,h,k,u,h,a,h,v,b,n,e,u,f,d,k,m,h,e,d,d,c,j,el,i,u,b,n,f,d,x,t,j,t,c,d,j,r,v,r,i,k,d,m,z,n,h,x,p,e,t,q,q,a,b,u,y,r,j,v,l,f,k,el,m,he,c,a,j,r,r,b,he,g,z,t,c,y,x,b,u,i,j,j,x,b,d,he,he,l,g,t,o,v,o,e,f,o,u,j,e,g,z,h,t,i,w,c,a,m,m,i,n,g,t,u,t,q,m,n,c,y,o,t,h,i,h,w,l,t,p,h,i,g,t,he,f,x,n,k,d,g,p,i,w,p,r,g,j,r,e,he,h,t,v,x,e,el,n,e,r,n,y,v,r,f,o,w,d,y,g,n,hel,c,he,k,x,q,k,q,h,l,d,l,he,i,w,h,l,b,k,y,k,h,e,s,s,g,y,x,n,p,c,k,l,he,l,g,k,s,hel,f,a,el,s,w,w,s,h,d,o,w,x,p,el,q,o,b,j,h,p,i,o,j,v,n,q,q,he,d,y,l,s,w,he,v,w,k,a,hel,b,h,t,a,u,s,s,x,y,b,p,d,e,l,y,m,x,w,s,t,hel,m,hel,x,h,p,c,u,h,q,a,i,hel,i,j,hel,x,hel,a,q,el,z,x,m,z,e,t,a,e,z,s,l,j,u,x,q,h,a,c,k,h,y,c,y,a,j,h,m,d,hel,r,q,v,a,f,el,v,p,i,el,c,n,p,a,r,o,s,o,a,hel,c,i,h,he,g,x,j,f,g,c,v,a,he,q,i,e,f,r,y,w,g,e,u,i,q,f,v,o,m,hel,c,u,h,d,o,p,y,s,p,he,el,v,hel,z,he,f,z,h,h,c,r,p,c,p,j,v,z,m,f,y,k,n,a,u,l,x,t,d,v,x,el,hel,e,i,p,c,n,hel,z,k,p,j,d,c,el,y,e,t,h,h,f,e,a,f,w,h,hel,e,el,n,el,m,l,x,t,el,o,t,n,t,o,h,el,c,x,v,hel,j,v,t,i,i,c,hel,p,t,h,z,q,p,w,h,w,x,u,k,q,b,e,w,q,j,s,y,b,i,h,a,c,q,g,hel,hel,l,he,b,d,y,m,hel,v,i,m,l,h,e,j,z,t,x,hell,k,m,y,v,d,n,s,hell,c,x,hel,a,u,hel,f,e,v,hel,c,hel,f,e,j,k,hel,y,x,t,e,hel,j,h,d,u,h,i,h,s,i,c,w,d,he,n,t,y,hel,he,m,hell,x,n,n,x,c,c,i,he,hel,b,j,j,y,v,a,a,g,n,he,v,r,i,p,c,o,r,t,s,hel,hel,y,l,y,e,r,g,b,h,he,el,u,q,i,hel,b,hel,i,w,m,u,q,j,c,b,j,l,s,w,o,s,u,s,c,l,el,s,d,o,q,j,j,e,hell,c,m,x,a,he,n,q,v,s,u,hell,n,e,n,c,x,m,v,v,z,v,b,h,f,o,u,m,l,h,he,el,n,el,b,z,a,o,w,l,i,j,el,n,f,i,e,p,m,c,hel,p,b,j,k,e,u,y,he,v,e,h,i,x,j,o,f,j,o,o,hell,q,d,n,m,j,n,a,a,el,n,b,n,y,a,t,y,f,f,l,p,c,w,el,g,el,hel,j,d,n,he,he,z,a,e,c,w,b,e,el,b,x,n,a,a,x,y,a,hel,a,hell,he,g,g,c,q,l,z,o,x,y,h,r,o,he,q,x,q,x,hell,a,l,o,e,l,k,l,m,w,lo,he,x,l,l,x,o,z,j,i,b,d,g,h,he,i,el,q,l,k,k,a,hel,ll,h,z,m,b,m,j,y,ll,s,v,u,ll,ll,f,f,p,p,m,d,g,g,lo,e,l,w,el,s,el,k,r,c,u,g,hell,o"
word = "hello world", alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" -> " ,k,l,q,x,w,d, ,a,o,b,v,h,n,n,i,l,f,u,t,u,n, ,g,j,s,t,i,g,d,f,g,b, ,o,f,t,x,d,q,w,k,d,t,n,d,v,h,e,m,he,s,b,h,w,l,h,x,e,j,o,g,i,f,f,c,h,k,a,y,z,r,j,l,v,k,i,he,p,x, ,f,u,m,d,p,c,s,p,y,e,k,w,u,q,f,f,s,f,f,a,z,w,l,e,v,q,a,r,y,l,u,he,x,z,z, ,k,k,k,i,u,m,q,k,t, ,l,k,he,y, ,z,l,he,x,x,w,n,w, ,l,v,c,o,h,g,e,b,n,q,j,a,c,p,j,he,p,r,w,c,s,l,j,g,j,x,y,i,c, ,q,c,i,j,v,s,r,a,z,c,d,m,f,w,i,z,a,s,t,l,he,a,r,r,he,a, ,v,q,o,r,y,b,n,j,k,d,m,i,t,b,v,q,y, ,y,l,he,r,or,r,t,b, ,a,q,z,h,l,e,w,y,l,t,o,or,d,l,j,h,g,e,h,y,g, ,x,k,g,he,b,r,or,he,he,g,m,t,he,s,j,c,d,v,l,he,e,a, ,or,h,h,g,or,j,u,l,f,o, ,p,k,z,g,q,u,h,j,k,o , ,r,he,o ,e, ,g,x,o,v,b,t,f,q,d,w,p,o,u,j,c,q, ,t,k,q,or,a,he,h,g,v,t,j,g,or,x,h,t,s,t,i,he,d,q,y,t,d,b,d,o ,g,l,l,he,n,e,v,y,x,or,y,g,he,p,k, ,x,d,c,o ,n,o ,or,s,v,q,o ,g,n,he,o,m,o,u,d,z,he,n,o,t,r,p,n,g,g,w,m,o ,b,h,s,or,or,a,n,m,z,r,u,e,i,h,m,v,g,o,g,f,k,p,j,t,v,d,k,c,m,h,x,z,f,f,d,e,o,h,a,m,b,or,ll,k,m,b,e,f,y,or,l,u,v,x,u,h,x,n,p,orl,p,k,p,b,y,x,x, ,a,a,he,a,i,h,d,x,w,or,j,w,wor,ll,h,x,orl,f,j,b, ,c,z,h,z,q,s,h,n,u,he,k,v,x,orl,w,u,r,m,h,g,p,b,j,a,g,i,h,b,d,r,a,k,i,orl,he,l,l,t,ll,or,o,q,ll,j,q,d,h,k,o,n,d,k,e,x,a,d,h,p,c,h,f,i,x,i,e,p,hel,o,he,or,r,s,e,g,j,u,v,v,f, ,e,y,o,u,ll,hel,f,c,n,v,x,f,h,w,x,b,o ,r,h,k,a,x,g,f,s,o,s, ,a,orl,l,v,o ,d,i,orl,x,e,wor,orl,hel,v,wor,f,l,t,j,i,f,w,o ,e,c,y,f,z,v,t,hel,or,s,n,y,g,w,hel,c,v,x,i,j,f,o,j,z,a,p,ll,x,m,e,r,o ,g,q,f,i,j,b,y,v,b,q,e,o ,y,orl,g,v,wor,p,wor,w,d,s,o ,k,h,t,or,a,v,r,p,s,i,t,y,g,l,z,y,a,u,f,c,p,p,b,orl,h,a,g,x,g,s,n,f,x,u,s,b,i,wor,orl,r,orl,f,ll,or,hel,wor,d,d,a,x,hel,o,hel,e,m,wor,f,e,k,x,a,d,p,o ,k,orl,m,m,hel,z,g,j,c,f,j,u,ll,h,d,e, ,t,j,c,f,wor,he,p,orl,d,r,orl,hel,q,b,b,wor,y,p,u,he,z,b,he,h,s,ll,y,wor,a,t,b,c,z,y,y,v,b,o ,d,b,or,s,d,k,q,l,x,b,p,orl,e,x,wor,ll,orl,y,o,l, ,a,g, ,x,d,e,wor,y,t,w,orl,c,f,s,i,c,hel,z,i,w,hel,f,i,y,ll,e,x,g,orld,wor,he,n,c,or,x,ll,ll,s,l,t,ll,l,p,q, ,w,worl,a,q,he,i,x,l,hel,g,o , w,m,c,o ,l,z,worl,j,i,y,n,b, w,b,wor,f,r,u,j,l,u,f,z,z,m,c,orld,c,e, w,ll,m,x,y,u,j,t,hel,o ,b,wor,he,m,d,n,f,orld,or,u,i,i,e,c,q,b,t, w,p,c,t,orl,p,c,o ,q,hel,w,orld,c,e, w,orl,b,r,u,y,ll,g,wor,hel,n,s,d,g,y,j,b,t,q,wor,hel,hel,s,y,b,a,or,n,h,orld,hel,orl,k,ll, ,f,z,o ,u,o, worl,he,o,v,e,or,r,wor,wor, worl,h,he,q,c,q,hel,orld,or,u,p,v,hel,ll,or,x,he,o ,q,ll,he,d,x,o ,orl,o ,z,o,b,world,g,or,s,v,a,o ,r,f,hel,i,r,c,s,q,ll,s,u,h,n,u, w,or,u,world,v,m,w,l,x,wor,o ,n,x, wor,a,g,orl,c, ,n,l,o ,w,k,orld,a,w,x, w,g,hel, ,k,orl,orl,r,v,l,o,o,j,orl,o worl,r,s,worl,wor,l,v,o , worl,z,n,lo ,orl,or,s,hel,world,orl,c,u,hel,z,n,z,c,orl,o w,worl,he,e,b,h,f,u,w,k,orl, wor,k,wor,c,f,orl,o worl,f,y,lo ,x,v,l,o ,c,c,z,lo,a,u,hel,orld,world, worl,orl,y,k,ll,ll,e, wor,d,h,j,a,he,j,orl, w,s, wor,he,j,orld,worl,k,hel,u,b,hel,r,w,hel,g,hel,lo, w,o worl,lo ,w,world,o ,lo w,b,t,l,b,u,q,hello, worl,or,p,hello worl,u, ,o ,o w,hel,or,or,u,z, , ,h,hello,o ,z,t,k,q,b,o w,t,m,he,m,w,worl,t,p,hello worl,k,hel,world,z,c, , w,z,b,f,hel,world,r,x,d,o worl,he,x, w,s,i,orld,o,d,t,hello,r,world,j,hello worl,o worl,he,w,f,e, worl,wor,o, worl,o w,lo, wor,lo wor,s,i,b,o worl,m,b,p,v, worl,b,lo ,worl,world,lo wor,f,orl,y,e,x,k,a,x,e,g,s,j,orl, w,d,orl,worl,s,a,worl,lo wor,lo ,o worl,s,lo worl,w,t,hel,orld,orl, worl,b,ll,g,o ,j,he,lo worl,n, ,he,c,n, worl, ,o worl,orl,p,k,b,he,o worl,z,orl,e,a,k,or,o w,z,w,lo w,z,f,u,k,s,o,he,o worl,m,h,a,k,o w,m,b,a,o,lo w,m,o w,he,a,hello,z,lo ,r,b,ll,l,he,or,hel,u, wor,he,g,t,o ,x,v,world,he,p,w,orl,lo,worl,o w, worl,lo w,b,orl,o worl, wor,r,he,h,hel,q,t,u,lo,w, w,lo wor,d,lo worl,n,hello,lo ,he,hello,lo wor,ll,lo worl,he,z,worl,orl, w, worl,lo worl,g,world,j,z,j,o, wor, wor,b,c,p,orl, wor,p,g,y, worl, ,b,k,q,g,o w,o worl,o ,p,d,orl,lo w,lo w,z,he,n,world,wor,d, worl,or,lo wor, wor,l,t,wor,worl,e,m, worl,z,j,hel,h,or,x,k, w,s,s,hello,b,p,lo w,l,g,p,o worl,j,wor,m, w,o,t,u,u,o,orld,s,u, w,orl,he,world,d,t,g,l,u,hello,n,worl,o w,lo worl,d,p,orl,q,o wor,u,v,or,q,d,c,hello worl,he,j,r,world,wor,o wor,hel,world,l,orld,q,x,wor,x,o ,ll,hello, wo,r,lo wor, ,or,j,o worl,t,hel,n,o,p, w,b,world,world,he,lo world,v,or,wor,o,lo world,lo worl,f,hello worl,u,orl,d, ,wor,z,r,lo w,p,o worl,o wor,b,he,f,hello wo,j,o ,o,or,f, ,o w,d, worl,wor,hel,k,y,hel,x,o worl, wor,g,ll, worl, wor,n, wo,orl,hel, wo,s,orld,he,lo,he, worl,o w,lo world,p,lo ,a,o ,v,c,p,t,or, w,q,f,o , wor,o worl,p,s,world,v,m,w,s,r,a,g,orl, ,z,p,v,j,o,o,r,l,c,q,orld,r,l,g,d,rl,lo wor,k,w,o , ,x,k,o,i,z,h,n,t,n, worl,w,w,s, wo,hel,he,f,lo , ,o worl,s,p,hello worl,r,o w,o worl,o w,j,c,world,lo worl,o ,wor,z,y,lo world,lo world,orld,s,u,hello,orl,lo wor,r,or,t,l,m,ll,worl,b,u, wo,o ,t, ,or,ll,ll,o,o w,llo,e,s,b,t,z,d,u,world,p,orld,wor,hello worl,lo worl,p,a,lo w,orld,w,wor,o w,lo worl,w,j,lo worl, worl,s,g,k,a,o w, ,o,hel,o,s,wor,u,w,p, wor,y,ll,he,j,orld,hello worl, worl,g,ll,o,lo worl,n,o,o worl,orld,m,lo,rl,o ,wor,hello worl,e,t,ll,g,d,d,orl,n,k,x,lo worl,a,q,wor,lo wor,lo worl,rl,o ,a,ll, wo,s,w,o w,e,h,lo,wor,o ,c,or,f,z,hel,lo worl,j,i,b,d,rl,lo ,j,j,o w,llo,i,b,z,c, worl,worl,e,o w,m, worl,wor,v,lo worl, ,r,u,y,g, w,m,r,ll,b, worl,g,o wor,b,a,m,n,orld,he,wor,hello,lo worl,orld, worl, , worl,o,q,b,o,e,rl,u,or, wo,u,o wor,hello worl,ll, ,llo,h, , ,wor,rl,y,l,z,he,orld,lo wor,x,g,n,b,world,j,ll,m,x,x,rl,n,lo worl,o worl,b, w, wo,b,z,x,o,v,or,t,hello,w,p,a,o,p,llo, ,y,d,p,h,c, wor,b,r,rl,u,c, worl,llo ,i,lo ,o ,q,p,w,he,he,b,lo,a,z,a,e, wor,v,or,hello wo,lo wor,m,hello worl,lo world,hello,v,worl,hel,s,llo ,e,d,o w,world,lo wor,lo ,hello worl,worl,w,w,orld,hello,o w,q,u,o ,worl,l,a,w, , wor,u,y,rl,s,p,o w,g,a,rl,v,y,orl,worl,o worl,rl,wor,x,u,or,s,orld,x,o ,q,p, w,z,u,t,d,a,orl,ll,o ,r,i,k,lo wor,p,b,a,ll,d,z,hello worl, ,hello worl, wor,o w,world,ll,world,hello,lo worl,k,llo ,hel,e,or,rl,hello,v,q, wo,lo wor,e,s,o,wor,lo ,o w,o ,or,x,wor,d,q,d,wor,hello wo,world, wo,a,llo ,worl,orld, wor,y,y,lo wor,o w, w,o,k,k,o ,b,llo worl,orld,worl,llo worl,ll,y,lo worl, wo,llo,hello,p, wo,u,hello worl,lo wor,m,n,orl,r,s,a, wor,wor,x,lo,u,lo world,lo world,s,o wor,o ,a,he,q,b,o,rl,o w,q,n, w, worl,e,a,k,o w, wor,a,f,o,hello worl, worl,o wor,z,g,s,o w, ,hello,hel,lo,i,lo worl,g,t,lo,lo world,rl,lo wor,o,t,ll,x,w,g,k,v,rl,he,y,hel,world,o wor,a,lo ,b,orl,lo, worl,q,o worl,world, w,hello wo,h,o ,o ,wor,hello,hel,lo ,b,q,o w,l,t,n,llo,e,q,q,q,lo worl,hello wo,orld,hello wo,h,x,p,z,hel,n,w,f,o wor,w,h,or,u,s,hello worl,hello ,d,d,rl,hello worl,wor,orl,hello,world,ll,lo,m,hello ,d,lo ,i,lo wor,orld,o ,z,m,hello wo,llo worl,ll,lo worl,world,hello ,llo,hello,e,rl,worl,h,llo worl,u,llo ,world,r,y,lo wor,g,z,d,worl,m,or,llo, wo,or,he,x,o worl,i,hello worl,k,f,w, w,o ,lo world,lo w,i,a,w,o ,z,r,hello ,hello ,hello worl,x,s,llo wo,u,worl,hello, worl,hello worl, ,world,t,llo world,rl, ,p,l,lo,lo w,worl,l, , ,rl,llo wo,h,o worl,llo worl,s,s,a,he,orld,p,lo ,i,f,hello wo,a,llo worl,llo,llo wo,he,llo ,b,ll, w,lo worl,i,t,k,world,r,llo ,lo worl,o w,d,j,lo worl,t,w,world,a,s,hello worl,or,hello wo,o ,llo wo, wo,u,orld,hello ,hello , worl,u,n,z,lo,o worl,llo , , wo,e,o wor,x,lo , w, world,s,hello ,lo world, world,worl, worl,b,h,h,q,world,s,c,lo w,d, ,l,hello worl,g,wor,or,t,x,i, worl,lo wor,s,p,s,llo worl,lo world,p,orld,f,k, w,orl, world,i,lo,orld,d,p,b, worl, ,world,b,b,ll,orl,l,a,llo ,p,k,world,i,hel,m,lo world,lo world,rl,world,d,q,r,he,j,hello worl,t,v,llo wo,p,d,g, world,world,r,hello,c,hello worl,llo world,lo world,z,m,t,q,j,t,m,d,n, worl,r,hello worl,lo worl,orl,p,hello ,g,o,rl,c,d,ll,lo w,o w,w,wor,orl, worl,llo world,y,llo world,o w, worl,c,g,lo worl, ,q,lo ,h,he,lo w,worl,lo worl,orld,m,u,wor, w,llo world,q,e,p,hello wo,hello worl,worl, world,s,o ,o ,d,o worl,n,x,world,hello worl,hello ,lo world, wo,x,rl,x,s,llo,lo ,a,hello ,e,q,lo w,world,x,i,o wor,w,z,s,o ,k,k,g,llo ,i,hello wo,lo w, worl, w,c, wor,c,c,lo , wo,lo world,lo,o wor,k,world,o wor,y,lo ,q,s,s, worl,hello ,lo , wor,orl,lo wor,llo,hello wo,wor, w,f, wo,w,k,r,j,o ,orld,i,or,p,b,rl,l,llo,e,rl,o,or,v,hello wo,lo ,w,j,w,hello,o w,hello worl,lo worl,e,i,llo,r,llo ,u,x,w,m,worl,h,wor,o, ,lo,o w,f,hel,c,lo world,b,a,llo worl,g,d,j,k,x,hello wo, world,o wor,llo world,hel,h,llo world,t,q,llo worl,x,h,lo ,v,or,b,u, wor,d,e,b,h,x,w,llo ,h,w, worl,o,hello, w, w,d,hello w,t,q,hello wo,llo wo,rl,m,lo wor,r,lo ,o w,hello,llo world,s,k,q,orld,y,v,hel,l,hello wo,w,a,orld,e, ,p, wor, wo,llo,wor,t,hello worl,f,hello w,wor,lo world,or,j,lo,d,i, worl, ,l,o ,wor,lo worl,g,b,m,s,s,ll,worl,orld,he,hello,rl,q,q,c,o worl,x,llo world,b,rl, ,d,ll,o, ,x,rl, wo,v,hel,llo world,l,hello,n,or,d,he,llo world"
word = "code golf and coding challenges", alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz " -> too large to fit in post
```

Comment: Is this similar: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147174/thats-a-lot-of-monkeys

Answer (score 0):

String to Lojban!

**In the constructed language Lojban, you can express ASCII strings with a literal quote, for example
 `zoi zoi \d+(\.?\d+) zoi`.
However, how would you pronounce that?**

```
zoi zoi backslash d plus opening bracket backspash dot question mark 
backslash d plus closing bracket zoi
```

**? Non-English speakers won't understand you.
However, there are several ways to assign Lojban words or phrases to ASCII characters. One is shown in the challenge.**

So here is the challenge:

The input is a string. You can assume it is composed of only the 95 printable ASCII characters.

The output is a Lojban representation of the string. It should start with `me'o` , followed by the following substrings in order:

```
SP -> canlu bu
!  -> saibu
"  -> lubu
#  -> libu
$  -> meryru'u bu
%  -> ce'obu
'  -> y'y
&  -> joibu
(  -> tobu
)  -> toibu
*  -> pi'ibu
+  -> su'ibu
,  -> slaka bu
-  -> vu'ubu
.  -> denpa bu
/  -> fe'ibu
0  -> no
1  -> pa
2  -> re
3  -> ci
4  -> vo
5  -> mu
6  -> xa
7  -> ze
8  -> bi
9  -> so
:  -> zo'ubu
;  -> pi'ebu
<  -> me'ibu
=  -> dubu
>  -> za'ubu
?  -> paubu
@  -> zvati bu
[  -> veibu
\  -> lu'ebu
]  -> ve'obu
^  -> te'abu
_  -> dizlo bu
{  -> lu'ibu
|  -> jabu
}  -> lu'ubu
~  -> nabu
```

This is a modification of [an existing system which can represent all 95 printable ASCII characters.](https://mw.lojban.org/papri/List_of_ASCII_letterals)

For lowercase letters, just add `y` after the letter, with these exceptions:

```
a  -> abu
e  -> ebu
h  -> y'y bu
i  -> ibu
o  -> obu
q  -> ky bu
u  -> ubu
w  -> vy bu
```

You can also use `tau y'y` for `h`.

For uppercase letters, use `tau`  followed by the corresponding lowercase letter, however `h` must be 
`tau y'y bu`.

After that, the substrings are joined with a single space, however for readability, no spaces are used between digits.

However, if the string is empty, output `lo kutyuenzi`.

Examples:

```
Input -> Output
1 2 -> me'o pa canlu bu re
Hello -> me'o tau y'y bu ebu ly ly obu
1234 -> me'o parecivo
12>1 -> me'o pare za'ubu pa
\d+(\.?\d+) -> me'o lu'ebu dy su'ibu tobu lu'ebu denpa bu paubu lu'ebu dy su'ibu toibu
 -> lo kutyuenzi
```

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 0):

[Spot The Difference](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/270086/spot-the-difference)

Comment: [You should clarify what you mean by randomly filled](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/92727)

Answer (score 0):

## Morph a string into another

Given two strings consisting of only printable ascii, at least how many operations are needed to morph string a into string b?

The allowed operations are:

- Take two characters x and y and make every instance of x in string a y.
- Pick a letter l and delete all instances of it from either a or b, but not both. After deleting a letter l once, you may not delete that same letter l from either a or b again.

For instance, given a = "abc" and b = "ccc", the minimum number of operations is 2.

```
morph a -> b => bbc
morph b -> c => ccc
```

If no such sequence of morphs exists, output a value that is distinctable and would never be outputted with any possible input.

### Test cases

```
"abc", "ccc" => 2
"abc", "abcz" => 1
"abbac", "ccbab" => -1
```

Comment: You should be more clear about what string a and b are in the example given. It can't be `a -> b -> c` if you are trying to get from a to b. also, is it really morphing a to b when you are changing both a and b?

Comment: Also, you can do the last test case in 4 moves.
"ccbab" -> "cca", 
"abbac" -> "bbc" -> "bba" -> "cca"

Answer (score 0):

[Find the odd one out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271383/find-the-odd-one-out)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but I hope you realize this is extremely easy, Vyxal and a few other golfing languages have 1-byte solutions for this

Comment: I don’t think that’s a good reason to add arbitrary tasks to your still simple challenge

Comment: If you create a new challenge you should create a new sandbox post, not edit an old one

Answer (score 0):

## [Contract a tensor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271329/contract-a-tensor)

Answer (score 0):

### Define a set containing N elements [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Consider a simple language that allows making basic statements about sets. It is defines as follows:

- `= 0 1` Sets 0 and 1 are equal. Variables are referenced using [De Bruijn Indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index)
- `< 0 1` Set 0 is an element of set 1
- `& a b` Expression A and expression B
- `! a` Not A
- `A a b` B holds for all elements of A. Defines a new variable

We use polish notation here, a simpler format that avoids much parsing.

### Challenge

Given a number N. give an expression in this language that will return true if the first variable is a set that contains exactly N elements. The formula does not need to be optimal.

### Examples

- `0`: `A 0 ! = 0 0` (All elements must not be equal to themselves)
- `1`: `& ! A ! = 0 0 A 0 A 1 = 0 1` (Not all elements are not equal to themselves, and all elements must equal all other elements)
- `2` `& ! A ! = 0 0 & ! A 0 A 1 = 0 1 & A 0 A 1 A 2 ! & ! & ! = 0 1 ! = 1 2 ! = 0 2` (For each set of 3 elements, at least 2 must be equal)

There are many different ways to encode a given number, you may pick any of them arbitrarily.

Goal is to make the generating code as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Rotation by triple skewing

You can rotate a two-dimensional array by an angle by sampling or some other mechanism to approximate the resulting value at a specific point. However this is not very effective for a small array, such as an ASCII-art picture. Instead, we can approximate the rotation by a triple skew.

The first skew shifts the rows of the array by an amount proportional to the distance above or below the centre of rotation. This value is an input which I shall call \$ t \$.

The second skew shifts the columns of the array by an amount \$ \frac{-2t}{1+t^2} \$ multiplied by the distance to the left or right of the centre of rotation.

The third skew is a copy of the first skew.

The shift amounts should be one of rounded, floored or ceilinged so that each row or column is shifted by an integer amount.

The array should be considered to be cyclic so that elements shifted will wrap around to the other side.

Given an input array, a centre of rotation, and \$ t \$, output the resulting rotated array.

The array may be any convenient data type such as bytes, characters or integers. If the array is of characters then you may also represent it as a list of strings.

Example of the three skews for \$t=0.475\$:

```
  012       012          27DE      27DE 
 34567     34567        16CJK     16CJK 
89ABCDE    89ABCDE     05BIQR     05BIQR
FGH IJK -> FGH IJK -> 34A PVW -> 34A PVW
LMNOPQR    LMNOPQR    89HOUZ     89HOUZ 
 STUVW       STUVW    FGNTY       FGNTY 
  XYZ         XYZ     LMSX        LMSX
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program that breaks no standard loopholes wins!

Answer (score 0):

## Near-repdigit perfect powers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

### Background

A *repdigit* is a positive integer whose digits are all the same in base 10. A *perfect power* is an integer that can be made by raising an integer to the power of 2 or higher, i.e. \$a^b\$ where \$a, b\$ are integers and \$b \ge 2\$.

\$6^5 = 7776\$ is an interesting number. It is a perfect power, and it is only 1 away from a repdigit \$7777\$.

But apparently there are very few perfect powers which are 1 away from a repdigit (my program only gives `4, 8, 32, 7776`), so it probably doesn't make a good code golf challenge. So let's relax the condition a bit: **we will find all positive *near-repdigit* perfect powers**. To be precise, we will use the definition from [1]: A near-repdigit is a \$k\$-digit positive integer such that \$k \ge 2\$ and exactly \$k-1\$ of the digits are the same.

[1] provides the full list of perfect *squares* that are near-repdigits:

```
16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 121, 144, 225, 441, 484, 676, 1444, 44944
```

plus the trivial ones in the form of \$a \times 100^i\$, where \$a\$ is one of 1, 4, or 9.

[2] provides another result for perfect cubes and higher powers. It shows that, not counting the trivial ones \$10^i\$ and \$8 \times 1000^i\$, the list of near-repdigit perfect powers for any specific exponent is finite. The full list of nontrivial solutions are not given. I ran my program up to \$10^{24}\$ but did not find any non-square ones except `27, 32, 343, 7776`.

The following is the list of all near-repdigit perfect powers up to \$10^{10}\$.

```
16, 25, 27, 32, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 225, 343, 400, 441, 484,
676, 900, 1000, 1444, 7776, 8000, 10000, 40000, 44944, 90000, 100000,
1000000, 4000000, 8000000, 9000000, 10000000, 100000000, 400000000,
900000000, 1000000000, 8000000000, 10000000000
```

[1] A. Gica and L. Panaitopol, [On Oblath’s problem](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Panaitopol/panaitopol41.html)

[2] O. Kihel and F. Luca, [Perfect Powers With All Equal Digits But One](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251282896_Perfect_Powers_With_All_Equal_Digits_But_One)

### Task

Output this sequence. You can use any of [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O methods:

- Without input, output the sequence infinitely.
- Given \$n\$, output the \$n\$th number of the sequence (0- or 1-indexed).
- Given \$n\$, output the first \$n\$ numbers of the sequence.

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

---

### Meta

- Might change the task depending on how the [related question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467034/524721) turns out. A strong candidate is to output the trivial ones:

  ```
  100, 400, 900, 1000, 8000, 10000, 40000, 90000, 100000,
  1000000, 4000000, 8000000, 9000000, 10000000, 100000000,
  400000000, 900000000, 1000000000, 8000000000, ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

## Soundex [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

[Note: This question was asked previously but it was not very well specified. I'd like to ask it again with a proper spec](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3119/91213)

Given a string containing only ASCII lowercase letters, output its [Soundex code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex). Soundex is an algorithm originally described by Donald Knuth to give words that sound similar the same index, as a form of fuzzy searching.

We'll use a slightly  modified version that removes the padding step. It works as follows:

- Remove all instances of `h`, `w`, or `y` except the first letter
- Replace all remaining consonants, except the first letter, based on the following table:

| Consonant | Code |
| --- | --- |
| b, f, p, v | 1 |
| c, g, j, k, q, s, x, z | 2 |
| d, t | 3 |
| l | 4 |
| m, n | 5 |
| r | 6 |

- Remove any successive instances of the same number. Also remove any numbers after the first that would have the same number as the first letter
- Finally, remove all the vowels, except the first letter

### Worked out example

- Lets take the string "squeezers"
- First, we remove all `h`, `w`, or `y`s. There aren't any.
- Then, we replace all consonants except the first with numbers. This creates `s2uee2e62`
- Now we remove all successive duplicates. We remove the first `2` since `s` would map to `2`. This creates `suee2e62`
- Finally, we remove vowels to create `s262`

### Test Cases

| Word | Soundex |
| --- | --- |
| squeezers | s262 |
| batman | b355 |
| robert | r163 |
| roberto | r163 |
| clarinet | c4653 |
| amazing | a5252 |
| whole | w4 |
| hole | h4 |
| asbestos | a21232 |
| yankee | y52 |

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Cyclic maximal words are also known as Lyndon words (the usual definition is for minimal words, but that doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 0):

## Find the missing side in a right triangle

You've solved for the legs when you have the hypotenuse. You've solved for the hypotenuse when you have the legs. But can you code golf a program to do both?

**Input**: three lines from `stdin`, for `leg a`, `leg b`, and `hypotenuse`. One line will be blank, which is the variable your program must solve for. All input will be integers.

**Output**: The missing side, as a float with at least 3 digits after the decimal. Leading and trailing whitespace is OK.

**Scoring**: Least bytes wins!

Comment: I suggest not being so strict with input and output. We typically allow function input in addition to stdin, as well as fractions in addition to floats.

Answer (score 0):

Given a non-negative integer,

1. Write the integer into base64, and store into bytes
2. Set each bit 7 to 1 but the last byte.
3. Set each bit 6 to 1 but the first byte.

In this way an integer has clear edges. Notice that 0x80 is unused.

### Questions:

1. Given an input, encode it.
2. Given some bytes, decide whether it's complete, incomplete or invalid.
3. Given some bytes, assuming not invalid, decode all numbers inside.

### Test cases

```
         0 => 00
        63 => 3F
        64 => 81 40
       132 => 82 44
      4096 => 81 C0 40
```

### Sandbox Notes

- Is such encoding named?

Answer (score 0):

Choose a language or its subset, write a program in it that, compute some function bool f(Program P, Int T) such that:

- If f(P,T), then f(P, T+1)
- lim[T->∞] f(P,T)=true iff P halts

---

### Notes:

- This is a component for a bounded busy beaver solver, by storing the program with largest running time. This task actually asks for a definition of running time.

Comment: This is fairly similar to [Compute the Uncomputable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225601/compute-the-uncomputable-sort-of). Also, does the program have to be in the same language or just in any turing complete language?

Answer (score 0):

Input part of staff, output its midi.

Symbols:

- `0`-`9`: octave symbol. Set O = the value.
- `CDEFGAB`: a note.
- - If octave is just set, then use the octave.
- - Otherwise, if the distance to last note is larger than 5 (`C-A`, `D-B` or `C-B`),
- - - Increase O by 1 if the new note is `C` or `D`; decrease if `A` or `B`.
- - Output O*12+{C:0, D:2, E:4, F:5, G:7, A:9, B:11}+K[O,c]
- `#`, `b`, `##`, `bb`, `%`: accidentals. Set K[next note] to 1, -1, 2, -2, 0, respectively.
- `|`: bar line. Reset accidentals. (Since beats are not given, bar line doesn't have other meaning.)
- You can assume all outputs are in [0,127], accidentals appear before octave if both exist, no double octave, octave or accidental to bar line, first note has octave provided

Test cases:

```
4CCGG|AAG => 48,48,53,53,55,55,53
4CDEFGAB|C4G5C => 48,50,52,53,55,57,59,60,55,60
5E#DEDE4B%DCA => 64,63,64,63,64,59,62,60,57
4C#CFAC => 48,49,53,57,60
#0D#E||##F#G#A#B||##C#D => 3,5,7,8,10,12,14,15
0EDCB => (invalid)
A#|B => (invalid)
10C => (invalid)
#9B => 120
9BCDEFG => 119,120,122,124,125,127
9BCDEFGA => (invalid)
```

---

- Should I have key signatures?
- Should I shift octave by 1?
- `s` and `f` or `#` and `b`?
- are triple accidentals allowed?

Comment: I would keep it simple: note to midi rather than staff to midi to avoid confusing nonmusicians, so no key signatures and no multiple flats/sharps. `#`` and `b` are used almost universally. That leaves the choice of natural symbol, I would probably go for something nonalphanumeric like `~` or `&`  . I suppose you could keep the bar to reset accidentals to avoid making it too simple.

Comment: The octave change needs some thinking about. I would suggest sticking with the standard octave `CDEFGAB`, although this means octave change when you move between nearby B and C. I appreciate what you're trying to do with your "larger than 5" system but the interval (at least if expressed in letters) needs to be smaller. `C to F` could be a default up change, and `C to G` a default down change. C to G is known as a fifth in 1-indexed musical notation, though it's actually only a change of 4 letters in 0- indexed.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I'm recently on Braille Music, where 4th and 5th by default remain in same octave. Lilypond just use the nearest one, though

Answer (score 0):

## Is the triangle decided?

Given some angles and edges of a triangle, decide if it's decided, impossible or multi possibility.

Input:

3 angles and 3 edges. Choose a non-positive value, maybe 0 or non-number, as input to mean not provided. Order is flexible, like [a,b,c,A,B,C], [A,b,C,a,B,c], etc.

Output:

3 values, representing decided, impossible or multi possibility.

---

- Allow different placeholder for angle and edge?
- Due to imperfect float, extra condition(AAAS) would likely make it wrongly claim impossible. Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

## Number houses in a street

House numbering varies across the world, and sometimes within a country, but the traditional numbering system in my country is to have the odd numbers ascending on one side of the street and the even numbers ascending in the same direction on the other side of the street. Here is an example:

```
9 |
  | 10
  | 8
7 |
5 |
  | 6
  | 4
3 |
1 |
  | 2
```

Here there are two detached houses, one at each end of the street, and four pairs of semi-detached houses. The empty spaces are probably where the garages and driveways are, but they are not relevant here, so I have left them out.

Your challenge is to write a program or function that will take an unnumbered street and number it.

You can input the houses in any convenient way, so you could take input as a diagram but with the houses marked by a fixed placeholder (e.g. `?`), or you could take a pair of lists of distances of each house from the start of the street (so for the above example the input could be `[[1, 2, 5, 6, 9], [0, 3, 4, 7, 8]]`.) Note that there may be two houses directly opposite each other, and there may also be different number of houses on each side of the street.

As well as numbering from the bottom left up, you may also number from the top right down, like this:

```
 2 |
   | 1
   | 3
 4 |
 6 |
   | 5
   | 7
 8 |
10 |
   | 9
```

The house numbers on the left of the street must be right-justified and those on the right of the string must be left-justified. The street can be marked with any fixed non-empty non-numeric string of your choice; it doesn't have to be  `|` .

In addition to the above two output formats, I will also allow any rotations (but not transpositions) of the above output formats, in case that is helpful for you, e.g.

```
 0
 18  64  2
==========
9  75  31
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Input:

a byte array of length 1 to 31, inclusive.

Take an example, `oxDE, 0xAD`

#### Objective:

Write each byte into 8-bit binary, big-endian `1101111010101101`

Average split into 8 parts `11 01 11 10 10 10 11 01`

Convert each part from binary to number `[3,1,3,2,2,2,3,1]`

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

- Which endian, or allow both?

Comment: I think a "challenge" should have a title. I do not understand `Average` - average of *what*, and where do I miss it used in the example? `number` looks like "Hindu-Arabic"/"ordinary" digit (representation, not concept (number)).

Answer (score -1):

## Consecutive Composites

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a positive integer **N**, finds the first block of **N** consecutive [composite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number).

This should be the *first* block of integers which fit the requirements, larger than 0. For example, with an input of **2**, the output must be **[8, 9]**, and not **[14, 15]**.

**Rules:**

- The numbers in the block should be printed or returned as a list, in any reasonable format.
- Submissions may be either full programs which perform I/O, or functions - no snippets.
- You can assume that the block of numbers your program has been request to find is within your language's standard integer range.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program (in bytes) wins! Standard golfing loopholes apply.

---

## Test Cases

```
1 -> [1]
2 -> [8, 9]
5 -> [24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
6 -> [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]
10 -> [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123]
```

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)

Comment: This is essentially http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23844/194 with a tweaked output format.

Comment: One is not a composite number, the smallest is four, so the test case for `1` should be `[4]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan i've misused the term composite there, I meant 'non-prime' - regardless, I probably won't post this anyway and Peter pointed out it's basically a dupe.

Answer (score -1):

**Wifi Puzzle! Crack the router**
[code-golf] [networking]

**SITUATION**

Consider that you have three wifi routers in your home , all with different SSIDs and none of them are dualband. You have invited a mischievous friend to your home who had changed the password of each router, without letting you know about it. Now to annoy you more he has set up a programming challenge.

**THE CHALLENGE**

Your friend has created three .txt files containing a set of passwords with only one correct among them. (i.e. each .txt file contains a correct password while all other are wrong ones. Also one .txt file contains only one correct password) and the .txt files do not specify which one may contain the correct password for a certain router (i.e. you cannot be sure that file1.txt(let us assume it is one of those .txt files) contains the password for router1( say any one of those routers). Now your friend has kept them in a certain directory( say E:\Wifi) and asked you to create a programme or function that would pick up a file and take input from it, try to connect to a random Access point ( out of the three routers) and find which password fits to which router.

**Sample Input**

Let us consider a file, file1.txt( or any other name you like) be like this

```
A12e77799U5
Pdc555089rtf
Ds442Y779#1
1&2*fe$996Yt
Uty66%92Gu4
```

Note that each password contains a capital letter, numbers, special characters, (of a standard keyboard) and each file contains only five unique passwords. Also all the .txt files are in the same directory and there are no subdirectories in the directory concerned. Also each .txt file contains at least one correct password.

**Sample Output**

Your programme or function must keep a log of its activity in a separate file log.txt which you may put in the same directory concerned or in a different directory. The log file must show which router has been cracked with which password and also the file containing it.

Example: Say that router1 ( SSID of a router)  has been cracked by the password A12e77799U5 from file1.txt so the output of the log.txt must be

```
router1 password A12e77799U5
File: file1.txt
```

Also you must be sure that all the output goes into the log.txt not seperate files each time a router is cracked. You can create a programme or a function in any programming language.

**Keep In Mind**

1. This is code-golf so the shortest answer wins.
2. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) apply as usual.

**Discussion**
I feel to ask this question but the foremost problem I face is how can others test their code. Also strict I/o rules (like the log.txt I mentioned ) are not appreciated here. 
So please help me out!

Comment: So, you want us to access the network settings programmatically? Even if we disregard the difficulties in testing it, this is not a golfing challenge, but rather a challenge in convincing our OSes to let us fiddle with the settings, and then figuring out how.

Comment: So is there any category I can put it in, I mean any tags.

Answer (score -1):

## Portable bitmap checkerboard pattern

Your task is to create a checkerboard pattern and store it in a  [PBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

Size of the checkerboard is passed in STDIN as two numbers.
Output is written to STDOUT.

Test case:

```
Input:
5
5

Output:
P1
5 5
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins

Answer (score -1):

## Highest code size∕output ratio to generate a large executable section inside an elf file.

Your challenge is to create the shortest code in your language of choice or the tools of your choice *(like objcopy)* that will **create an [elf file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) with a the executable section as large as possible**.
I mean that if I extract the`.text` section of the [elf binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), the resulting extracted file should be at least 90% of the [elf binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

## Requirements

- **The program should takes the desired section size as input**.
- The `.text` section name needs to corresponds to the executable section.
- The type of the `.text` section should be`PROGBITS`and it should contains instructions.
- The elf file should have a `.shstrtab` section.
- The `.text` section should be readable and writable.
- The target architecture should be Pnacl or armelv7 or x86_64.
- The [elf file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) should be valid and pass Google nacl’s [validation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/src/native_client.git/+/master/src/trusted/validator_arm/armv7.table) [whitelist](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/src/native_client.git/+/master/src/trusted/validator_ragel/instruction_definitions/) in order to be loaded *(but I don´t care if the sandbox segfault)*.
  If you have **no idea about what Google native client is**, just create a **script that call the patched version of binutils from the nacl_sdk**, or make sure the elf file is valid and can be executed on Linux.

Of course, you normally can’t use a compiler because it would takes too much computational years in order to finish.

## Winner

The answer with the highest code size∕program output ratio.

Comment: Why not make scoring `output size / code size`?

Comment: Make it a [tag:code-challenge]

Comment: This is essentially the same challenge as [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69189/194), and would be closed as a duplicate. Although it's not exactly the same, some answers to the previous question would require very little modification and answers to this question would also require very little modification to be answers to the other one.

Comment: @Alt-F4 : it was a code challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : they were no answer to the previous question. In order to be closed as a duplicate the target needs to be already answered. You known it was closed an unclear, **so please suggest change to make this answer clearer**.

Comment: Huh? It's open and has 15 answers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor sorry, I thought to an another question that was closed as unclear and didn’t take time to read your link. In that case **NO**, the aim is to not use the compiler in order to actually build the file. This normally can’t be done with a compiler or an assembler.

Comment: Can't it? Why not?

Comment: Wait... shortest code that generate any program? Or what? Don't think this is a good idea...

Answer (score -1):

## Proper Kerning

[Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) is the adjustment of spacing between pairs of letters in order to obtain an aesthetic result. When kerning is applied automatically by a program (typically whatever editor you're using), it is said to be automatic. There are two types of automatic kerning. The one used in this challenge is **metric** kerning. With metric kerning, the amount of space between pairs of letters is dictated by the kerning tables found in the font file.

Given a TrueType font file, output the kerning values for each mapping in the kerning table for ASCII characters 48 - 122 inclusive.

### Example

calibri.ttf

```
l="A" r="C" v="-15"
l="A" r="G" v="-15"
l="A" r="J" v="23"
l="A" r="O" v="-23"
l="A" r="Q" v="-23"
l="A" r="T" v="-160"
l="A" r="U" v="-32"
l="A" r="V" v="-89"
l="A" r="W" v="-80"
l="A" r="Y" v="-150"
l="A" r="t" v="-52"
l="A" r="v" v="-38"
l="A" r="y" v="-41"
l="A" r="?" v="-68"
l="B" r="A" v="-20"
l="B" r="T" v="-48"
l="B" r="V" v="-25"
l="B" r="W" v="-24"
l="B" r="X" v="-44"
l="B" r="Y" v="-57"
l="B" r="Z" v="-20"
l="B" r="f" v="-20"
l="B" r="t" v="-20"
l="B" r="v" v="-20"
l="B" r="x" v="-15"
l="B" r="y" v="-20"
l="C" r="G" v="-18"
l="C" r="J" v="12"
l="C" r="O" v="-18"
l="C" r="Q" v="-18"
l="C" r="T" v="10"
l="D" r="A" v="-30"
l="D" r="J" v="-22"
l="D" r="T" v="-23"
l="D" r="V" v="-24"
l="D" r="W" v="-14"
l="D" r="X" v="-31"
l="D" r="Y" v="-39"
l="D" r="Z" v="-22"
l="E" r="A" v="-22"
l="E" r="C" v="-24"
l="E" r="G" v="-24"
l="E" r="O" v="-32"
l="E" r="Q" v="-32"
l="E" r="S" v="-20"
l="E" r="Z" v="-10"
l="E" r="a" v="-34"
l="E" r="c" v="-28"
l="E" r="d" v="-30"
l="E" r="e" v="-37"
l="E" r="f" v="-64"
l="E" r="o" v="-37"
l="E" r="q" v="-30"
l="E" r="t" v="-24"
l="E" r="v" v="-48"
l="E" r="w" v="-34"
l="E" r="y" v="-48"
l="F" r="A" v="-115"
l="F" r="C" v="-18"
l="F" r="G" v="-18"
l="F" r="J" v="-109"
l="F" r="O" v="-18"
l="F" r="Q" v="-18"
l="F" r="S" v="-29"
l="F" r="X" v="-22"
l="F" r="Z" v="-11"
l="F" r="a" v="-55"
l="F" r="c" v="-28"
l="F" r="d" v="-20"
l="F" r="e" v="-30"
l="F" r="o" v="-28"
l="F" r="q" v="-20"
l="F" r="s" v="-35"
l="G" r="T" v="-10"
l="G" r="V" v="-10"
l="G" r="W" v="-9"
l="G" r="Y" v="-30"
l="G" r="v" v="-29"
l="G" r="w" v="-22"
l="G" r="x" v="-14"
l="G" r="y" v="-30"
l="J" r="A" v="-35"
l="J" r="X" v="-20"
l="K" r="C" v="-78"
l="K" r="G" v="-80"
l="K" r="O" v="-97"
l="K" r="Q" v="-97"
l="K" r="S" v="-18"
l="K" r="U" v="-29"
l="K" r="W" v="-34"
l="K" r="a" v="-34"
l="K" r="c" v="-40"
l="K" r="d" v="-33"
l="K" r="e" v="-37"
l="K" r="f" v="-25"
l="K" r="m" v="-32"
l="K" r="n" v="-32"
l="K" r="o" v="-37"
l="K" r="p" v="-32"
l="K" r="q" v="-33"
l="K" r="r" v="-32"
l="K" r="s" v="-18"
l="K" r="t" v="-38"
l="K" r="u" v="-32"
l="K" r="v" v="-101"
l="K" r="w" v="-95"
l="K" r="y" v="-85"
l="L" r="C" v="-22"
l="L" r="G" v="-47"
l="L" r="J" v="25"
l="L" r="O" v="-45"
l="L" r="Q" v="-45"
l="L" r="T" v="-150"
l="L" r="U" v="-44"
l="L" r="V" v="-147"
l="L" r="W" v="-118"
l="L" r="Y" v="-167"
l="L" r="f" v="-23"
l="L" r="t" v="-38"
l="L" r="v" v="-78"
l="L" r="w" v="-72"
l="L" r="y" v="-79"
l="O" r="A" v="-23"
l="O" r="J" v="-27"
l="O" r="T" v="-55"
l="O" r="V" v="-25"
l="O" r="W" v="-22"
l="O" r="X" v="-64"
l="O" r="Y" v="-55"
l="O" r="Z" v="-38"
l="O" r="x" v="-12"
l="O" r="z" v="-10"
l="P" r="A" v="-151"
l="P" r="J" v="-140"
l="P" r="T" v="-9"
l="P" r="V" v="-10"
l="P" r="X" v="-35"
l="P" r="Y" v="-11"
l="P" r="Z" v="-29"
l="P" r="a" v="-44"
l="P" r="c" v="-43"
l="P" r="d" v="-34"
l="P" r="e" v="-41"
l="P" r="f" v="12"
l="P" r="o" v="-41"
l="P" r="q" v="-34"
l="P" r="s" v="-32"
l="P" r="t" v="12"
l="P" r="y" v="12"
l="Q" r="J" v="41"
l="Q" r="T" v="-47"
l="Q" r="V" v="-25"
l="Q" r="W" v="-12"
l="Q" r="X" v="12"
l="Q" r="Y" v="-46"
l="Q" r="g" v="59"
l="Q" r="j" v="79"
l="Q" r="x" v="31"
l="Q" r=";" v="60"
l="Q" r="]" v="32"
l="R" r="C" v="-18"
l="R" r="G" v="-19"
l="R" r="O" v="-20"
l="R" r="Q" v="-20"
l="R" r="S" v="-27"
l="R" r="T" v="-20"
l="R" r="V" v="-28"
l="R" r="W" v="-18"
l="R" r="Y" v="-30"
l="R" r="e" v="-36"
l="R" r="o" v="-42"
l="R" r="v" v="-26"
l="R" r="w" v="-33"
l="R" r="y" v="-33"
l="S" r="A" v="-15"
l="S" r="J" v="-9"
l="S" r="T" v="-14"
l="S" r="V" v="-14"
l="S" r="W" v="-15"
l="S" r="X" v="-13"
l="S" r="Y" v="-20"
l="S" r="v" v="-23"
l="S" r="w" v="-17"
l="S" r="y" v="-25"
l="T" r="A" v="-160"
l="T" r="C" v="-42"
l="T" r="G" v="-59"
l="T" r="J" v="-65"
l="T" r="O" v="-58"
l="T" r="Q" v="-58"
l="T" r="S" v="-10"
l="T" r="T" v="28"
l="T" r="a" v="-160"
l="T" r="c" v="-177"
l="T" r="d" v="-147"
l="T" r="e" v="-182"
l="T" r="g" v="-151"
l="T" r="m" v="-127"
l="T" r="n" v="-127"
l="T" r="o" v="-182"
l="T" r="p" v="-127"
l="T" r="q" v="-147"
l="T" r="r" v="-127"
l="T" r="s" v="-153"
l="T" r="u" v="-127"
l="T" r="v" v="-92"
l="T" r="w" v="-86"
l="T" r="x" v="-90"
l="T" r="y" v="-93"
l="T" r="z" v="-142"
l="T" r=";" v="-114"
l="T" r=":" v="-134"
l="U" r="A" v="-45"
l="U" r="J" v="-40"
l="V" r="A" v="-96"
l="V" r="C" v="-18"
l="V" r="G" v="-25"
l="V" r="J" v="-80"
l="V" r="O" v="-27"
l="V" r="Q" v="-27"
l="V" r="S" v="-12"
l="V" r="V" v="9"
l="V" r="a" v="-114"
l="V" r="c" v="-103"
l="V" r="d" v="-87"
l="V" r="e" v="-102"
l="V" r="g" v="-100"
l="V" r="m" v="-50"
l="V" r="n" v="-50"
l="V" r="o" v="-86"
l="V" r="p" v="-50"
l="V" r="q" v="-87"
l="V" r="r" v="-50"
l="V" r="s" v="-90"
l="V" r="u" v="-50"
l="V" r="y" v="-35"
l="V" r="z" v="-82"
l="V" r=";" v="-108"
l="V" r=":" v="-73"
l="W" r="A" v="-93"
l="W" r="C" v="-22"
l="W" r="G" v="-22"
l="W" r="J" v="-88"
l="W" r="O" v="-22"
l="W" r="Q" v="-22"
l="W" r="S" v="-10"
l="W" r="X" v="-13"
l="W" r="a" v="-71"
l="W" r="c" v="-78"
l="W" r="d" v="-72"
l="W" r="e" v="-75"
l="W" r="g" v="-54"
l="W" r="m" v="-60"
l="W" r="n" v="-60"
l="W" r="o" v="-86"
l="W" r="p" v="-60"
l="W" r="q" v="-72"
l="W" r="r" v="-60"
l="W" r="s" v="-73"
l="W" r="u" v="-60"
l="W" r="v" v="-34"
l="W" r="y" v="-53"
l="W" r=";" v="-156"
l="X" r="C" v="-57"
l="X" r="G" v="-65"
l="X" r="O" v="-57"
l="X" r="Q" v="-57"
l="X" r="S" v="-20"
l="X" r="d" v="-44"
l="X" r="e" v="-39"
l="X" r="g" v="-9"
l="X" r="o" v="-38"
l="X" r="q" v="-44"
l="X" r="t" v="-31"
l="X" r="u" v="-38"
l="X" r="v" v="-55"
l="X" r="w" v="-49"
l="X" r="y" v="-43"
l="Y" r="A" v="-152"
l="Y" r="C" v="-67"
l="Y" r="G" v="-67"
l="Y" r="J" v="-112"
l="Y" r="O" v="-66"
l="Y" r="Q" v="-66"
l="Y" r="S" v="-17"
l="Y" r="Z" v="-10"
l="Y" r="a" v="-134"
l="Y" r="c" v="-159"
l="Y" r="d" v="-131"
l="Y" r="e" v="-147"
l="Y" r="f" v="-62"
l="Y" r="g" v="-142"
l="Y" r="i" v="-32"
l="Y" r="j" v="-49"
l="Y" r="m" v="-94"
l="Y" r="n" v="-94"
l="Y" r="o" v="-153"
l="Y" r="p" v="-94"
l="Y" r="q" v="-131"
l="Y" r="r" v="-94"
l="Y" r="s" v="-115"
l="Y" r="t" v="-44"
l="Y" r="u" v="-94"
l="Y" r="v" v="-69"
l="Y" r="w" v="-62"
l="Y" r="x" v="-70"
l="Y" r="y" v="-65"
l="Y" r="z" v="-100"
l="Y" r=";" v="-138"
l="Y" r=":" v="-154"
l="Z" r="A" v="-11"
l="Z" r="C" v="-25"
l="Z" r="G" v="-24"
l="Z" r="O" v="-24"
l="Z" r="Q" v="-24"
l="Z" r="W" v="-7"
l="Z" r="Y" v="-7"
l="Z" r="a" v="-10"
l="Z" r="c" v="-12"
l="Z" r="d" v="-18"
l="Z" r="e" v="-31"
l="Z" r="o" v="-29"
l="Z" r="q" v="-18"
l="Z" r="v" v="-45"
l="Z" r="w" v="-38"
l="Z" r="y" v="-37"
l="a" r="f" v="-12"
l="a" r="t" v="-19"
l="a" r="v" v="-34"
l="a" r="w" v="-14"
l="a" r="x" v="-19"
l="a" r="y" v="-38"
l="b" r="f" v="-17"
l="b" r="s" v="-10"
l="b" r="t" v="-9"
l="b" r="v" v="-10"
l="b" r="w" v="-10"
l="b" r="x" v="-41"
l="b" r="y" v="-10"
l="b" r="z" v="-28"
l="c" r="a" v="-17"
l="c" r="o" v="-17"
l="e" r="f" v="-18"
l="e" r="t" v="-11"
l="e" r="v" v="-10"
l="e" r="w" v="-10"
l="e" r="x" v="-31"
l="e" r="y" v="-13"
l="e" r="z" v="-20"
l="f" r="a" v="-40"
l="f" r="c" v="-45"
l="f" r="d" v="-53"
l="f" r="e" v="-51"
l="f" r="f" v="-20"
l="f" r="g" v="-60"
l="f" r="o" v="-43"
l="f" r="q" v="-53"
l="f" r="s" v="-27"
l="f" r="v" v="13"
l="f" r="w" v="6"
l="f" r="y" v="10"
l="f" r="z" v="-20"
l="g" r="a" v="-38"
l="g" r="c" v="-12"
l="g" r="d" v="-19"
l="g" r="e" v="-17"
l="g" r="g" v="19"
l="g" r="o" v="-14"
l="g" r="q" v="-19"
l="g" r="t" v="-31"
l="h" r="f" v="-12"
l="h" r="t" v="-19"
l="h" r="v" v="-34"
l="h" r="w" v="-14"
l="h" r="x" v="-19"
l="h" r="y" v="-38"
l="k" r="a" v="-35"
l="k" r="c" v="-48"
l="k" r="d" v="-56"
l="k" r="e" v="-66"
l="k" r="o" v="-69"
l="k" r="q" v="-56"
l="k" r="s" v="-19"
l="k" r="t" v="-10"
l="k" r="u" v="-26"
l="m" r="f" v="-12"
l="m" r="t" v="-19"
l="m" r="v" v="-34"
l="m" r="w" v="-14"
l="m" r="x" v="-19"
l="m" r="y" v="-38"
l="n" r="f" v="-12"
l="n" r="t" v="-19"
l="n" r="v" v="-34"
l="n" r="w" v="-14"
l="n" r="x" v="-19"
l="n" r="y" v="-38"
l="o" r="v" v="-9"
l="o" r="w" v="-8"
l="o" r="x" v="-40"
l="o" r="y" v="-11"
l="o" r="z" v="-27"
l="p" r="f" v="-17"
l="p" r="s" v="-10"
l="p" r="t" v="-9"
l="p" r="v" v="-10"
l="p" r="w" v="-10"
l="p" r="x" v="-41"
l="p" r="y" v="-10"
l="p" r="z" v="-28"
l="q" r="g" v="10"
l="r" r="a" v="-42"
l="r" r="c" v="-30"
l="r" r="d" v="-28"
l="r" r="e" v="-27"
l="r" r="g" v="-28"
l="r" r="o" v="-33"
l="r" r="q" v="-28"
l="r" r="s" v="-35"
l="r" r="v" v="19"
l="r" r="w" v="11"
l="r" r="y" v="10"
l="s" r="f" v="-19"
l="s" r="t" v="-23"
l="s" r="v" v="-31"
l="s" r="w" v="-10"
l="s" r="x" v="-22"
l="s" r="y" v="-37"
l="s" r="z" v="-18"
l="t" r="a" v="-25"
l="t" r="c" v="-25"
l="t" r="d" v="-23"
l="t" r="e" v="-22"
l="t" r="o" v="-20"
l="t" r="q" v="-23"
l="t" r="t" v="-29"
l="v" r="a" v="-30"
l="v" r="c" v="-25"
l="v" r="d" v="-20"
l="v" r="e" v="-20"
l="v" r="f" v="11"
l="v" r="g" v="-28"
l="v" r="o" v="-19"
l="v" r="q" v="-20"
l="v" r="s" v="-9"
l="v" r="t" v="10"
l="v" r="v" v="12"
l="v" r="w" v="12"
l="v" r="y" v="12"
l="v" r="z" v="-26"
l="w" r="a" v="-23"
l="w" r="c" v="-20"
l="w" r="d" v="-18"
l="w" r="e" v="-18"
l="w" r="f" v="6"
l="w" r="g" v="-18"
l="w" r="o" v="-19"
l="w" r="q" v="-18"
l="w" r="s" v="-18"
l="w" r="t" v="4"
l="w" r="v" v="12"
l="w" r="w" v="8"
l="w" r="y" v="12"
l="w" r="z" v="-17"
l="x" r="a" v="-37"
l="x" r="c" v="-46"
l="x" r="d" v="-44"
l="x" r="e" v="-54"
l="x" r="o" v="-55"
l="x" r="q" v="-44"
l="x" r="s" v="-12"
l="x" r="t" v="6"
l="x" r="u" v="-20"
l="y" r="a" v="-31"
l="y" r="c" v="-26"
l="y" r="d" v="-24"
l="y" r="e" v="-25"
l="y" r="f" v="10"
l="y" r="g" v="-26"
l="y" r="o" v="-24"
l="y" r="q" v="-24"
l="y" r="s" v="-19"
l="y" r="t" v="10"
l="y" r="v" v="12"
l="y" r="w" v="8"
l="y" r="y" v="10"
l="y" r="z" v="-17"
l="z" r="a" v="-34"
l="z" r="c" v="-45"
l="z" r="d" v="-46"
l="z" r="e" v="-46"
l="z" r="f" v="-10"
l="z" r="g" v="-17"
l="z" r="o" v="-45"
l="z" r="q" v="-46"
l="z" r="s" v="-22"
l="z" r="u" v="-10"
l="z" r="v" v="-18"
l="z" r="w" v="-22"
l="z" r="y" v="-18"
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

#### Meta

I know this challenge is going to need a lot of work before it's ready for main. Please hold criticisms for now. Helpful ideas and thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is well defined. There's a reason it's called *font hinting*: the rendering application is free to take it into account or not, or even to apply more complex logic. E.g. some fonts have multiple sets of font hints for different contexts. There are other complex issues. A font can have Latin and Cyrillic letters and define hints for kerning between pairs of Latin and pairs of Cyrillic but not between Latin and Cyrillic; however, some letters may have identical glyphs, so a judgement on whether the kerning is "correct" might be ambiguous. Then there's antialiasing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good notes. I will likely restrict the character set. I just wanted to start getting ideas down in the sandbox.

Comment: Very ambiguous.

Comment: @Mendeleev It's not done yet. I'm aware it's ambiguous.

Comment: Looking at https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6kern.html I can see a number of issues to address. 16- vs 32-bit entries? Should multiple tables be combined or printed separately? All tables or only tables with certain `coverage` values? Which of the four defined formats need to be supported? Do you have a test case which covers glyph index differing from codepoint?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have a proof of concept that I wrote (it's the reason I have taken so long to update this) and I'm planning to address all of your questions. Thanks for doing a bit of research to help me out, though :]

Comment: Downvoter, why?

Answer (score -1):

## Bike saddle drawn through a fractal

Based on the [Mandelbrot image in every language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/mandelbrot-image-in-every-language), and on the observation the 3rd layer (0 indexed) always looks like a bike saddle, I had a little bit different challenge:

- Language must be capable of graphical output or drawing charts (saving files disallowed)
- Render a window or control that is resizable by mouse action. As example, it can be a typical GUI Window with the typical frame that allows resizing
- After resizing the GUI element, the fractal should be updated according to the new pixel space
- The fractal coordinates range from approximately -2-2i to 2+2i
- The pixels outside of the 3rd layer (0 indexed) of Mandelbrot set should have one color; the ones inside 3rd and inner layers should have another. The only two colors used should be clearly distinguishable
- At least 99 iterations
- ASCII art not allowed

**Winning conditions:**
Shortest version (size in bytes) for each language will get a mention in this post, ordered by size.
No answer will ever be 'accepted' with the button.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus: credits to you.

Comment: "The only two colors used should be clearly distinguishable" Clarification?

Answer (score -1):

## Do nothing

Write a program which terminates normally (not in an error), producing no output on the [standard output stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (or the language's closest equivalent), nor on the standard error stream, regardless of what content is present on the standard input stream. (Note that this is intentionally overriding the normal I/O defaults; this is a challenge entirely about input/output handling.)

Additionally, your program may not have any other side effects (e.g. writing files, changing persistent state), unless they're an unavoidable consequence of running a program on the operating system you're using (e.g. on Linux, it's OK to change the "next process ID number to be assigned" value inside the kernel, because that happens whenever you run a program).

Finally, to avoid numerous uninteresting 0-byte (or boilerplate-plus-0-byte) solutions, you may not use a language in which the shortest program that does nothing (i.e. complies with the above specification) is also the shortest (or tied for the shortest) program which runs without error (but possibly reacts to input or produces output). In other words, you can't use a language unless doing nothing is more verbose than doing something.

### Clarifications

- Intentionally exiting the program early is permitted. If you do exit the program manually, on a system that uses exit codes, you may do so with any exit code.
- Crashing the program is not permitted, even if it (for some reason) exits with a "success" code after the crash.
- "No output" means 0 bytes of output, not even a trailing newline.
- Likewise, your program must be able to handle *any* finite sequence of bytes on the standard input stream, even if it isn't, say, made of characters in the current encoding (but rather of arbitrary octets). You do not need to handle infinite input, though (e.g. your program won't be connected to `/dev/zero` or the like).
- You don't have to actually read input; it's your choice as to whether you want to read and discard it, or not read it at all.

### Victory condition

As a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, shorter is better, measured in bytes. (Remember that if you need to run the program in an unusual way, that incurs a byte penalty, under standard PPCG rules.)

Because languages which are particularly suited for this task (such as Perl and Python) are excluded by the rules, there's not much point in talking about the best answer cross-language; rather, the aim is to find the best answer you can in the language which you submit in. (Historically, on this sort of challenge, answers that are more unusual, interesting, or better-explained have tended to get more votes.)

### Sandbox questions

Is this too trivial? We were discussing it in chat as a joke, and realised that it's actually possibly more interesting than it sounds. I'm fairly sure the spec's correct (although would definitely appreciate knowing if something's wrong here!), but would appreciate feedback on how much people would hate me if I posted it to main.

Comment: *you can't use a language unless doing nothing is more verbose than doing something.* → *you can't use a program unless your program is more verbose than any other program which does something. You must provide a shorter program which does something to prove your solutions validity.*

Comment: @Adám: If you did that, people would just add a comment byte or two to create a program of the shortest possible length that was longer than a program that did something. That isn't particularly interesting.

Comment: So I write a buffer null that accepts input stdin > /dev/null I think it should do nothing. If it produces Moby Dick I will be surprised.

Answer (score -1):

## Plan and Chain a route through OEIS

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [bitwise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitwise) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Your Task is to reach so many OEIS sequences you could make with chaining your last sequence with a operation to a new sequence.

You must avoid last sequence minus last sequence plus first sequence or something similar that your new sequence is based on the first sequence except to make the second sequence.

Your starting OEIS sequence is in every case https://oeis.org/A001477

Given as Input an positive Integer and a Letter that matches [A-Z] or [a-Z]

### Example

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 171 bytes

```php
for($a=0;$a<=$argv[1];$a++)$r[]=[$a,$b=$a&1,$c=$a+!$b,$d=(($c-!$b)/2^0)+$b,$A[$b]=$e=$d*$c,$f=$e+$A[!$b],$g=$a?$g*sqrt($f):1,$h=$g%2];echo$r[$argv[1]][ord($argv[2])%32-1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDJTsMwEIbveQoTpihbiZ1u6mJVFeqBC1y4RaFyEmeR2jidpBx59TJQIS7hYs@Mv/n/GbdVe91s26q1NKLBA@rWYF83pfO5P7y8vj0/7d21BQrLDxnbYzuwBadD28n6Whh0QEm@BrWRP0gsEkp83wWMExmDCiCllwcRQEa3fwdpALl0HMjGFLth9M5d/7u4iyFNJGgJuQdZAAXFPlWJSgIoqXkLpdedsXegcFckWEkoR1Gy1lllyO7XP4kN5s4tixJ3NInGNNT1vsW66Q80MNI@oUcrsarv224VhkbX3aPBMtxxLqaLBWsup1RjZ0E6yHA@mbGTyVnELMgGEMGXczFhJs//pPIhTvD5bMqU07hMsuJo6EObMHKZz5qbgQV6eIRILFiPtWrKy1GhBcU/2JKz7nxRqC0ohxExjVihst6Q2tHywusX)

The example gives back the n value of a OEIS sequence for the following letters. A letter greater `h` is for this example a invalid input

- a https://oeis.org/A001477 numbers
  `$a` Valid first sequence
- b https://oeis.org/A000035 mod 2
  `$b=$a&1` Valid use the variable in the sequence before
- c https://oeis.org/A109613 odd numbers
  `$c=$a+!$b` Valid Can use sequences before
- d https://oeis.org/A110654 a(n) = floor(n/2) + n mod 2
  `$d=(($c-!$b)/2^0)+$b` Valid 
  an invalid example is `$d=(($a/2)^0)+$b` cause it not use the sequence before
- e https://oeis.org/A000217 triangular
  `$A[$b]=$e=$d*$c` Valid you can create help variables
- f https://oeis.org/A000290 square
  `$f=$e+$A[!$b]` Valid use a help variabale and the variable of the sequence before. `$f=$A[!$b]+$A[!$b]` Invalid causes it makes the same value but use indirectly the variable of the sequence before
- g https://oeis.org/A000142 factorial  `$g=$a?$g*sqrt($f):1` Valid
  cause your condition is not always the case that it have no
  relationship to the sequence before.
- h https://oeis.org/A019590 Fermat's Last Theorem  `$h=$g%2` Valid but now we have the problem to find the next sequence

Could You make a full alphabet? My alphabet ends with the letter h

Comment: I'm rather confused as to what is being asked here.  It might be helpful to state how one can get from one sequence to another.

Comment: @WheatWizard I  could understand you. The problem is at the moment to make rules that avoid that a trivial solution exits. There are too many  sequences in OEIS. The way from every sequence to the next should not end in a simple addition or multiplication. But evrything else should be allowed to get more creative solutions

Comment: (1) The first sentence says that the aim is to build the longest chain possible, but the scoring mechanism rewards average code length per element in the chain rather than number of chains. I would think it most likely as it stands that the winner would be a chain of length 1 or at most 2. (2) If you delete everything from the header **Example** to the end, do you think that the question still makes sense? If not (and I don't think it does), it needs a lot of work. (3) What do the two values in the input mean? Why is the second one a letter rather than a number?

Comment: (4) I'm not sure how feasible it is to write objective rules which forbid "trivial" expressions. (5) It is not clear how to interpret the rule about the 32nd term where either it is not known or the sequence is finite and shorter than 32 terms.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (1) Think you that popularity Contest is a better winning criteria? (2+3) to limit the chaining length to 26. The goal is to show  relationsships between two or more sequences. (4+5) Yes it is not easy and I can drop it if I switch to popularity Contest

Comment: @WheatWizard I allow now trivial solutions

Comment: I'm not clear on the purpose of the inputs if we're just supposed to hard code our way from one sequence to the next​. Replacing your PHP example with more generic, more verbose pseudo-code might help.

Comment: @programmer5000 exists a limit of correct tags?

Comment: @Shaggy See it as restriction for ways to code. You must have a chaining to the sequence before. So far I know any working code is a pseudocode

Answer (score -1):

### Braid Badly Boundlessly

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

Your program or function must, given a string in any standard input format, output an infinite stream of delimiter-separated strings where each string is determined from the previous by a braiding algorithm. The program starts with printing the input string.

The algorithm is described as follows: Infinitely alternate between

(1) splitting the string into three substrings then swapping the first two substrings and flattening.

and

(2) splitting the string into three substrings then swapping the last two substrings and flattening.

starting with (1).

The three substrings should be of non-increasing length with the maximum length no more than 1 greater than the minimum length of the three substrings. (This means that when the length of the given string is a multiple of three, the three substrings should be the same length. When the length of the given string is one more than a multiple of three, the first substring should be one character longer than each of the last two substrings. When the length of the given string is two more than a multiple of three, the first and second substrings should each be one character longer than the last substring.)

#### Example

Let the input be `"abcdefg"`. Let the delimiter be a newline.

Then the program would first print `"abcdefg"`.

It applies (1) which splits the string into `["abc","de","fg"]` and swaps the first two elements, reaching `["de","abc","fg"]`. It flattens to get `"deabcfg"` which it prints and uses for the next step.

The program applies (2) to `"deabcfg"` to split into `["dea","bc","fg"]` and swaps into `["dea","fg","bc"]`, flattening to reach `"deafgbc"`.

The program applies (1) to `"deafgbc"` and the process repeats ad infinitum.

Then the output would be the newline-separated

```
abcdefg
deabcfg
deafgbc
fgdeabc
fgdbcea
bcfgdea
bcfeagd
eabcfgd
eabgdcf
gdeabcf
gdecfab
cfgdeab
cfgabde
abcfgde
abcdefg
deabcfg
deafgbc
fgdeabc
fgdbcea
bcfgdea
bcfeagd
eabcfgd
eabgdcf
gdeabcf
gdecfab
cfgdeab
cfgabde
abcfgde
abcdefg
[...]
```

#### Specifications

- Note that the string should not be split at the beginning and then only swapped later. The string should be split on each and every iteration
- The delimiter between lines could be whichever character is convenient. You may assume it does not appear in the input string.
- The string input shall be at least three characters
- The input consists solely of printable characters (0x20-0x7F)
- Of course, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?answertab=votes#tab-top) are forbidden.

#### I/O

- The input and output should be taken in [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- The input and output should be taken as string, list of characters, or equivalent.
- The output should be output continuously, which means you may assume infinite memory.

#### Test cases

For the test cases, we will assume that the delimiter is a newline. Just the portion before the endless stream is repeats is shown.

```
input
--
output
-----
abcdefg
--
abcdefg
deabcfg
deafgbc
fgdeabc
fgdbcea
bcfgdea
bcfeagd
eabcfgd
eabgdcf
gdeabcf
gdecfab
cfgdeab
cfgabde
abcfgde
-----
abc
--
abc
bac
bca
cba
cab
acb
-----
abcdefgh
--
abcdefgh
defabcgh
defghabc
ghadefbc
ghabcdef
bcdghaef
bcdefgha
efgbcdha
efghabcd
habefgcd
habcdefg
cdehabfg
cdefghab
fghcdeab
fghabcde
abcfghde
abcdefgh
-----
Braid
--
Braid
aiBrd
aidBr
dBair
dBrai
radBi
raidB
idraB
idBra
Brida
-----
Cycle
--
Cycle
clCye
cleCy
eCcly
eCycl
yceCl
ycleC
leycC
leCyc
Cylec
-----
O Canada!
--
O Canada!
anaO Cda!
anada!O C
da!anaO C
da!O Cana
O Cda!ana
-----
A man, a plan, a canal - panama!
--
A man, a plan, a canal - panama!
an, a canalA man, a pl - panama!
an, a canal - panama!A man, a pl
 - panama!Aan, a canal man, a pl
 - panama!A man, a plan, a canal
 man, a pla - panama!An, a canal
 man, a plan, a canal - panama!A
n, a canal  man, a pla- panama!A
n, a canal - panama!A man, a pla
- panama!A n, a canal man, a pla
- panama!A man, a plan, a canal 
man, a plan- panama!A , a canal 
man, a plan, a canal - panama!A 
, a canal -man, a plan panama!A 
, a canal - panama!A man, a plan
 panama!A m, a canal -an, a plan
 panama!A man, a plan, a canal -
an, a plan, panama!A m a canal -
an, a plan, a canal - panama!A m
 a canal - an, a plan,panama!A m
 a canal - panama!A man, a plan,
panama!A ma a canal - n, a plan,
panama!A man, a plan, a canal - 
n, a plan, panama!A maa canal - 
n, a plan, a canal - panama!A ma
a canal - pn, a plan, anama!A ma
a canal - panama!A man, a plan, 
anama!A mana canal - p, a plan, 
anama!A man, a plan, a canal - p
, a plan, aanama!A man canal - p
, a plan, a canal - panama!A man
 canal - pa, a plan, anama!A man
 canal - panama!A man, a plan, a
nama!A man, canal - pa a plan, a
nama!A man, a plan, a canal - pa
 a plan, a nama!A man,canal - pa
 a plan, a canal - panama!A man,
canal - pan a plan, a ama!A man,
canal - panama!A man, a plan, a 
ama!A man, canal - pana plan, a 
ama!A man, a plan, a canal - pan
a plan, a cama!A man, anal - pan
a plan, a canal - panama!A man, 
anal - panaa plan, a cma!A man, 
anal - panama!A man, a plan, a c
ma!A man, aanal - pana plan, a c
ma!A man, a plan, a canal - pana
 plan, a cama!A man, anal - pana
 plan, a canal - panama!A man, a
nal - panam plan, a caa!A man, a
nal - panama!A man, a plan, a ca
a!A man, a nal - panamplan, a ca
a!A man, a plan, a canal - panam
plan, a cana!A man, a al - panam
plan, a canal - panama!A man, a 
al - panamaplan, a can!A man, a 
al - panama!A man, a plan, a can
!A man, a pal - panamalan, a can
!A man, a plan, a canal - panama
lan, a cana!A man, a pl - panama
lan, a canal - panama!A man, a p
l - panama!lan, a canaA man, a p
l - panama!A man, a plan, a cana
A man, a pll - panama!an, a cana
```

Answer (score -1):

## Lennyface parser and selector

### Your mission

Create, in the language of your choice, a program that outputs a randomly selected lennyface (artistic minifigures, see [this](http://textsmili.es/?cr=bW91dGh%2BNmRiX2V5ZXN%2BOTN6X2VhcnN%2BN2JvLjJqLTJsLjdicw%3D%3D)) from an input - a string composed of numbers and lennyfaces. You will have to : first, **parse** this input; second, extract a **probability mass function** `f` from the parsed input; third, **select and output** a lennyface respecting `f`. Read the **rules** for more details.

### Rules

- **Input** : A string with lennyfaces and numbers (positive AND negative integers), separated by newlines. You may take input by STDIN or function parameter for example.
- **Output** (STDOUT for example) : the randomly-selected lennyface, as a string.
- The input creates a probability mass function `f`. If `l` is a lennyface, then `f(l)=(sum of all numbers since the previous lennyface)/x` where `x` is obtained afterwards by summing each of those numerators. **@Sandbox : is it clear enough?**
- If `(sum of all numbers since the previous lennyface)` is equal to zero or negative, you must do as if the numerator is equal to `1` in `f`'s definition.
- A line with a number contains only this number ; same for a line with a lennyface. So you can assume there will never be a number in a lennyface.
- If there is nothing on a line (two newlines in a row), you must consider it as a lennyface.
- You must consider that the last line of the string is directly before its first line. See **Test 1** for an example.
- You can assume there will be at least 1 lennyface in the list; it cannot be composed just by numbers (don't forget that an empty line is a lennyface too).

### Example

Given this input list :

```
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
2
¯\_ツ_/¯
34
-4
8
└[⸟‿⸟]┘

1
```

You must have 1/42 chances of outputting `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)`, 2/42 chances of outputting `¯\_ツ_/¯`, 38/42 chances of outputting `└[⸟‿⸟]┘` and 1/42 chances of outputting nothing (line 7).

### Test cases

**Test 1**

```
(⌐■_■)
3
```

*Must output* `(⌐■_■)` *with 3/3 chances.*

**Test 2**

```
ʢ◉ᴥ◉ʡ
```

*Must output* `ʢ◉ᴥ◉ʡ` *with 1/1 chance.*

**Test 3**

```
0
\(ᗝ)/
```

*Must output* `\(ᗝ)/` *with 1/1 chance.*

**Test 4**

```
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
2
¯\_ツ_/¯
34
4
☞   ͜ʖ  ☞

0
```

*Must output* `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` *with 1/42 chance,* `¯\_ツ_/¯` *with 1/21 chance,* `☞   ͜ʖ  ☞` *with 19/21 chances and nothing with 1/42 chance.*

**Test 5**

```
1



( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
```

*Must output* `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` *with 1/4 chance and nothing with 3/4 chance, since there are 3 empty lines.*

**Test 6**

```
42

-1
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
```

*Must output nothing with 43/44 chance and* `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` *with 1/44 chance.*

**@Sandbox : should I add test cases?**

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.
[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

*Note : Please do not be discouraged if the parsing is difficult to handle in your language, or if testing is hard because of randomness. Your solution might be very interesting algorithmically, not obviously in terms of golfing. Just please explain in your answer why it works.*

*Moreover, this is the first code-golf I create, so please let me know if something is not appropriate or if I should give more details on a point. And overall, if you downvote, explain me why so I can improve it.*

Comment: Yours tests seems a bit contraditory. The number is the chance of the next face (line), so what's the point of the empty line in the example / test 4? By the same logic, the test1 should have a `3/4` of outputting nothing? What is the point of the `0` in the test 4?

Comment: Why is the chance of outputting `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` 1/42 and not 0 ? (since there are no numbers above it)

Comment: Sorry ! I forgot to copy paste the fact that the minimal chance is 1!

Comment: Also, a common thing to do on challenges involving randomness, and therefore, hard to test, is to ask people to provide a mandatory explanation, or at least ask them to show why it works.

Comment: @Dada thanks. I note this.

Comment: @Rod the empty line _is_ a lennyface, as said here : `If there is nothing on a line, you must consider it as a lennyface.`

Comment: @V.Courtois I meant and empty line without a preceding number

Comment: As I said, the minimum is one (sorry again for forgetting it).

Comment: If only positive integers are to be expected, you should write it. Otherwise, give some details and examples about what you consider "numbers".

Comment: @Dada editing. In fact I said the minimum is 1, but you can have things like 2,-1,-3,17 and then your lennyface ; that means the probability is 15/ total.

Comment: @V.Courtois just a small suggestion, to make the "list as circle" more explicit you could change the value to something else than `0` or `1`, this way it would not overlap the "missing number" rule

Comment: @Rod does it? Sorry if I'm not getting what you are saying, but the list is _always_ a circle, meaning if your list is 2,3,`( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)`,4,5,`☞   ͜ʖ  ☞`,6, you have 6+2+3 chance of getting `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` and 4+5 chance of getting `☞   ͜ʖ  ☞`.

Comment: thanks for editing @musicman523

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). This is far more complicated than common sense would require. Deliberately overcomplicating things to make it "more difficult" is a guaranteed method to make a bad question.

Comment: For real?! I thought it was some purpose of PPCG to make difficult things :l @PeterTaylor

Comment: The challenge has two parts as far as I can tell. a) Create a probability mass function from an input by parsing b) sample from the probability mass function. Part a) needs to be rewritten as it is at best ambiguous and at worst just incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

## Quick! Tell me all the numbers from 1 to 100,000! [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)[numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers)

Your task is to write a program or function that, when run, output all the numbers from 1 to 100 thousand as quickly as possible to STDOUT. It's that simple. All answers are tested on an [HP Compaq nx9420](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-nx9420-notebook/specs/) with an Intel Core Duo @ 1.83 GHz and 3 gigs of RAM using the `time` command.

---

Of course, standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden*.
This is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so may the fastest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: Have you tried running an example to see if the times are variable enough to be meaningful? As-is, this is going to be *strongly* dependent upon how fast the code can do I/O, which makes the challenge pretty uninteresting, IMO.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Might be interesting

Comment: As far as I can tell, this takes less than a tenth of a second, which means submissions will probably be differentiated solely by noise on your computer.

Comment: upvoted, though I think the differenciation is really difficult, unless you test it on a raspberry PI (for example) having ONLY the program and its compiler installed.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How could I improve on that?

Comment: @V.Courtois I do have a Pi, and I think I will use that (it has Raspbian installed).

Comment: The time is still so small even a basic operating system will have to much noise in process creation, etc, for this to work out. You need to make what we are computing substantially more complicated for this to be reasonable.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman K

Comment: @ckjbgames good then :)

Answer (score -1):

## What's that character? (Part 1) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Recently I ran a command on my laptop that returned a bunch of characters - some printable, some non-printable. I'm having trouble figuring out what those characters are, so I could use some help. Unfortunately, I'm running low on disk space, so you'll have to write me the shortest program you can that I can run.

## Challenge

Given a list of ASCII characters, return their names as written on [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/), my go-to site for looking up character points.

#### Input

You may take a string, a list of characters, or a list of ASCII code points (e.g. 'a' -> 97).

You may optionally take the length of the string/list as well. Note that for C, you must take this parameter, since the string could contain NUL bytes, so `strlen` won't work here.

#### Output

Output is flexible as usual; you may print or return from a function as you see fit. You should output a list of strings.

#### The Table

```
0 NUL
1 SOH
2 STX
3 ETX
4 EOT
5 ENQ
6 ACK
7 BEL
8 BS
9 TAB
10 LF
11 VT
12 FF
13 CR
14 SO
15 SI
16 DLE
17 DC1
18 DC2
19 DC3
20 DC4
21 NAK
22 SYN
23 ETB
24 CAN
25 EM
26 SUB
27 ESC
28 FS
29 GS
30 RS
31 US
32 Space
33 !
34 "
35 #
36 $
37 %
38 &
39 '
40 (
41 )
42 *
43 +
44 ,
45 -
46 .
47 /
48 0
49 1
50 2
51 3
52 4
53 5
54 6
55 7
56 8
57 9
58 :
59 ;
60 
63 ?
64 @
65 A
66 B
67 C
68 D
69 E
70 F
71 G
72 H
73 I
74 J
75 K
76 L
77 M
78 N
79 O
80 P
81 Q
82 R
83 S
84 T
85 U
86 V
87 W
88 X
89 Y
90 Z
91 [
92 \
93 ]
94 ^
95 _
96 `
97 a
98 b
99 c
100 d
101 e
102 f
103 g
104 h
105 i
106 j
107 k
108 l
109 m
110 n
111 o
112 p
113 q
114 r
115 s
116 t
117 u
118 v
119 w
120 x
121 y
122 z
123 {
124 |
125 }
126 ~
127 DEL
```

## Test Cases

```
[0, 97, 7, 22] -> [NUL, a, BEL, SYN]
```

More to come...

## Meta

- Would it be more interesting to use [the UTF-8 names](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for the printable characters (0x20 - 0x7E), and the ASCII names for the control characters?

Comment: `hand copy the table from the website` please dont. Try a Google search: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes.txt

Comment: @StepHen good call, thanks

Comment: Downvoter: _I would much like your feedback rather than just your vote_

Comment: IMO just have take a letter and output the code. Since that part is boilerplate `str.chars.map( real program )`. Also for ASCII char names `NUL`  is it ok is we output them in lower case? e.g. `nul` (obviously ascii letters would have fixed case)

Answer (score -1):

## Hungry for Apples?

[image]

This challenge is simple, given an integer `0 <= n` or `0 < n`, output an ASCII-apple with that many bites taken out of it.

---

**No bites (0):**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   ;          ;
  :            :
  :            :
  :            :
   :          ;
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 1:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   ;          ;
   '-.         :
     }         :
   .-'         :
   :          ;
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 2:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.        ;
     }         :
     }         :
     }         :
   .-'        ;
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 3:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.        ;
     }      .-'
     }      {
     }      '-.
   .-'        ;
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 4:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.      .-'
     }      {
     }      {
     }      {
   .-'      '.
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 5:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.      .-'
     }".    {
     } }    {
     } }    {
   .-'"     '.
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 6:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.      .-'
     }"~".  {
     } } }  {
     } } }  {
   .-'"~"   '.
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

**Bite 7:**

```
         //
     .-.:|.-.
   .'   ''   '.
   '-.      .-'
     }"~"~".{
     } } } }{
     } } } }{
   .-'"~"~" '.
   '.        :
     '-_.._-'
```

Bite >7:

```
[empty output]
```

---

## Rules

- You may have trailing spaces, make it consistent though.
- You may have exactly 1 trailing newline.
- You are NOT doing an animation here, you are taking in `n` and outputting an apple.
- You may error on integers less than 0, as the spec provides `n > 0`.
- You must have empty output (no error) on `n > 7/8`.

  - You threw out the core; you didn't error the core into non-existence.

This is [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[hungry-for-apples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungry-for-apples)

Comment: I feel this would be better if there was some more symmetry in the 5, 6, and 7 bytes so that people could possibly make better compression.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork better?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score -1):

## Golf Cubically code [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [fgitw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fgitw)

Your task is to optimize [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically) source code using one or more optimizations in this post.

How this challenge works:

- You will choose one or more optimizations below and write a program (in the language of your choice) that performs those optimizations on a Cubically program.
- Your program will take a Cubically program as input using any [allowed input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/61563), and output a Cubically program using any [allowed output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/61563).
- The first answer to successfully perform all optimizations wins!

## Optimizations

#### 1. Face turn arguments

Before a face turn is performed, the interpreter calculates `turns = turns mod 4`. So `R5` would be equivalent to `R1` which is equivalent to `R`, `R7` is equivalent to `R3` which is equivalent to `R'`, etc. Also note that `R11111` is equivalent to `R5`, and `R22` is equivalent to nothing at all.

Performing this optimization will mean evaluating all arguments to an `R`, `L`, `U`, `D`, `M`, `E`, or `S` command and shortening them as much as possible.

Test cases:

```
Relevant code -> Optimization
R11           -> R2
R1            -> R
L33           -> L2
U22           ->
D222          -> D2
M11111        -> M
E00001        -> E
S9            -> S
```

#### 2. Repeated face turn

When multiple calls to the same face turn command are present right next to each other, they can clearly be golfed. For example, `R2R1` is equivalent to `R3`. `UUU` is equivalent to `U3`. `F2F2F2F2` is equivalent `F8`.

Test cases:

```
Relevant code -> optimization
R2R2R2        -> R6            (R2 if you also choose optimization 1)
LLL           -> L3
UU            -> UU or U2
D3D2D1        -> D6            (D2 if you also choose optimization 1)
```

#### 3. "Set notepad to" commands

There are some commands that, instead of adding to/subtracting from/multiplying by/dividing by the notepad, just assign to it. Here are all such commands:

```
_^=<>⊕«»·|:
```

When called with multiple arguments, since each argument calls the command separately, only the final argument is relevant. So `=123` is equivalent to `=3`, `_00000` is equivalent to `_0`, and `:12345678987654321` is equivalent to `1`.

Test cases:

```
Relevant code -> Optimization
_333          -> _3
=12321        -> =1
+54321        -> +54321
:55           -> :5
/55           -> /55
```

#### 4. Repeated *non*-face-turn commands

When multiple face turn commands are present right by each other, their arguments can simply be added together. Commands do not act this way. While `R2` calls `R` with `2`, `=2` calls `=` with the face sum of the front face (face index 2).

To perform this optimization, when multiple commands outside of `RLUDFBMES` appear next to each other, simply remove the duplicated commands without removing the arguments.

```
Relevant code -> Optimization
_1_1_1_1      -> _1111         (_1 if you also choose optimization 3)
%11%22%33     -> %112233       (%3 if you also choose optimization 3)
+12345+67+8   -> +12345678
```

#### 5. Nonexistent commands

Go check out the [Cubically commands page](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/wiki/Commands) and you'll see that there are plenty of characters that are not commands. For example, there are no commands that are lowercase letters.

To perform this optimization, remove all nonexistent commands *and their arguments* from the Cubically source. If the commands also have arguments, you must remove the arguments so that they are not passed to the previous command.

Test cases:

```
Relevant code -> Optimization
moo cow moo   -> 
moo2cow2moo   -> 
misteR2 FOO   -> R2F
FEAR ME.      -> ERME
u1U2u3U4u5U6  -> U2U4U6   (nothing if you also choose optimization 1, U12 if you also choose optimization 2)
```

#### 6. Non-implicit commands

There are lots of implicit commands in Cubically (`RLUDFBMES()$~&E!`), but there are plenty that need to be called with arguments. So `%%%%` is equivalent to nothing at all while `%%2%%` is equivalent to `%2`.

Test cases:

```
Relevant code -> Optimization
%%%%          -> 
$$$$          -> $$$$
++2++2++2     -> +2+2+2                 (+222 if you also choose optimization 4)
+++>--<-      -> Not Brainf**k, sorry!  (:P)
```

## Sandbox

I'll add more optimizations later.

Comment: Clarification on R123: That's the same as R6 and R2, not R3, right? Digits are summed, there are multidigit numbers? That would be better to specify

Comment: A few things: first, I can't find the tag "fgitw", is there a typo? Second, does optimization 1 require handling `F` and `B` as well, or just the currently listed ones? Third, in optimization 3 most of the listed commands seem invalid because the notepad is used in calculation and then overwritten with the output; for example `=11` is not the same as `=1` in most circumstances. In fact, I think only `_:` are valid. Fourth, is the winning answer one which performs all optimizations in a single program, or one which contains a separate program for each optimization?

Answer (score -1):

**Six Flags over HTTP**

Let's say you need to transmit six boolean flags in a URL string. Obviously you could do it with six ones or zeroes, but you want better compression. With a little math you can pack them into two characters using 0-7 octal.

How about mapping all six to a single ASCII character? Here we have a problem: you are not allowed to use , / ? : @ & = + $ # or space. Now the range of printable ASCII no longer has 64 valid characters in a row.

In Javascript (or another language that can run from a web page, if any), what is the shortest code for a pair of functions to encode and decode this data, between an array of six booleans and a single character?

Comment: -1 language restriction, most languages have HTTP libraries so I think any language should be allowed

Comment: This challenge could be improved by rephrasing it to: "Write a bijective function between an array of six booleans and a single printable character **excluding the characters `,/?:@&=+$# `**". Mentioning that the encoder and decoder should be separate programs/functions would be helpful. Also, may the encoder and decoder share code?

Answer (score -1):

## Count letter frequency

Inspired by question [Tweetable hash function challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76781/tweetable-hash-function-challenge), you should take the [English dictionary](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/orlp/3ff520a34ad74d547557e761d92be470/raw/british-english-huge.txt) used there and produce a program or function that outputs the the absolute and relative frequency of each character. It is CASE SENSITIVE and the APOSTROPHE is also accountable as a real letter.

Example of a valid output format (but with stupid guessing values):

```
A      5566    20%
...
Z        60     0.2%
a     27000    30%
...
z       120     0.01%
'       450     3.5%
```

It is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but no answer will be accepted. Wanna know shortest script for each language.

Comment: -1 (01) Don't rely on another challenge to define yours; include all the information we need in your write-up. (02) Make an effort to come up with some actual test cases - do you honestly expect us to verify our solutions against "*stupid guessing values*"?

Answer (score -1):

## Is it a perfect loop? [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

Your task is to take a GIF or an animated image in any reasonable format as input (including taking the file name of a GIF in  the current directory), and output whether it is a "perfect loop" - that is, the frames transition seamlessly from the end to the start, and a human cannot notice where it starts and ends at first glance. Return or print a truthy value if it is a perfect loop, otherwise print or return a falsy value.

### Scoring

Winners will be determined from the percentage of test cases they get correct. In the event of a tie, highest votes wins. You can view test cases at https://ghostbin.com/paste/m3yaw. Show your score against the test cases when you post.

### Input

If you are not taking input in a GIF, please provide a program that will convert a GIF to your desired format.

Images corresponding to a truthy value have been taken from [/r/perfectloops](http://reddit.com/r/perfectloops) and for falsy test cases, [/r/almostperfectloops](http://reddit.com/r/almostperfectloops) and [/r/gifs](http://reddit.com/r/gifs).

### Restrictions

- Hard coding is not allowed (violates standard loophole [1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/26600) and [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/26600)).
- You must provide consistent results for the same GIF (no randomness)
- Remember, this is not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so byte count is not needed in your solution. Just post the language name and add the percentage correct when I comment.

Comment: I'm not sure it's as simple as comparing the first to the last frame, if it is we'd have duplicate frames. is this challenge allowing HTTP requests?

Comment: If hashing the inputs is not allowed, then you should clearly define what constitutes a “perfect loop”. It's not good to extrapolate from a handful of test cases where the pass/fail cases are very similar.

Answer (score -1):

## Removing a Letter adds a Letter

Your program should output nothing when unaltered, however, when any single character is removed it should have an output length of 1. This extends to any number of characters being removed from the program, as long as there is, at minimum, a single character remaining.

---

For example, if my program were `abcdefg`, it should output nothing if unaltered.

However, if I were to remove `a` and `d` from this program to get `bcefg`, it should output any two printable characters that represent 16 bytes of information (2 characters for 2 characters removed).

- So if `bcefg` outputs (`00`,`AA`,etc...) this is valid.

Taking this further, if we were to remove all but the letter `g` we'd need an output of 6 characters.

- So if `g` outputs ('000000','@$^%@(',etc...) this is valid.

Your program must function for all possible combinations of removals that are possible, that is to say each single letter in your program should be a valid program.

---

## Rules

- You may "lock" pieces of the code, each locked byte counts for 2-bytes instead of 1-byte.

  - Locked bytes will never be removed.
  - For instance, if my program was `abcdefg` and `bcd` is locked, the shortest program we'll get is `abcd`,`bcde`,`bcdf` and `bcdg`.
  - If `bcd` was locked in `abcdefg` it'd be 10 bytes, not 7.
- The program may output any byte to represent 1 removed character, N-bytes for N removed chars in the code itself.

Comment: The rule only leads to totally locked code

Comment: @l4m2 hah. I disagree.

Comment: But more constructively, increase the penalty? Limit locked chars?

Comment: Maybe require an unlocked percent?

Answer (score -1):

> Sandbox:
>
> Is this question already available (duplicate)?
>
> Are things too vague?
>
> Does providing the example help or hinder?

## Tidy the Pantry (easy)

I hate grocery shopping, particularly the part where I put groceries away--so I'm calling upon the collective hive-mind to handle that.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to take a 1D-list of groceries and a 2D pantry as input; and output an newly assorted pantry. The two variables can be of your type choice, and in any order, but please specify what item types your program requires (e.g. string, array, etc.).

### Rules & Additional info.

#### Scoring

- This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins

#### Rules

- The pantry should be ordered alphabetically (A - Z, left to right, top to bottom)

  - For simplicity, the pantry is case-insensitive
- The pantry must retain its horizontal size (but trailing newlines are optional)
- "Pockets" (empty spaces) should be filled between items (i.e. only the last item is allowed to have a trailing pocket)
- If the pantry is too small for the incoming groceries, then the pantry must replace older items (`Z` being the oldest, `A` the youngest)

  - `Z` from `groceries` is younger than `A` in `pantry`
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden

---

### Examples (`[` and `]` are used for readability)

Input (4x4 `pantry`):

```
[A][A][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][B][ ]
[C][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][D]

AAD
```

Output:

```
[A][A][A][A]
[B][C][D][D]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

---

Input (2x2 `pantry`):

```
[A][B]
[C][D]

XYZ
```

Output:

```
[A][X]
[Y][Z]
```

---

#### Example solution

## JavaScript ES6 (989 bytes)

```js
// (String, String) -> String
let organise = (pantry, groceries) => {
  let n = pantry.split("\n").sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length); // used at the end of the function for horizontal sizing
  n = n[0].length;

  pantry = pantry
    .replace(/\W/g, "") // get rid of all non-alphanumeric characters
    .split("");         // turn the string into an array

  // we need the properties of the new array
  // so the extra `pantry = pantry` is needed
  pantry = pantry
    .slice(0, pantry.length - groceries.length) // go ahead and remove the last overlapping elements
    .concat(groceries)                          // add the groceries to the pantry
    .join("")                                   // turn into a string
    .split("")                                  // turn into an array
    .sort()                                     // sort the array
    .join("");                                  // turn into a string

    return pantry.replace(RegExp(`(.{${n}})`, 'g'), "$1\n");
};

/** Testing below **/

console.log("Test #2:\n" + organise(
`AJCHDJE
JJ   JA
    ASD
OOQ I U
Q     W
      R`,

'AHJBCJHDHHATTGEH'
))
```

---

### Test Cases:

#### Test #1, 4x4 pantry

```
TVCX <- pantry
ABCD
ATDJ
UAIK

XYXY <- groceries
----
AAAB <- expected output
CCDD
IJKT
XYXY
```

#### Test #2, 7x6 pantry

```
AJCHDJE
JJ   JA
    ASD
OOQ I U
Q     W
      R

AHJBCJHDHHATTGEH
-------
AAAAABC
CDDDEGH
HHHHJJT
T
```

#### Test #3, 10x10 pantry

```
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
----------
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
ZZZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

## Test #4, 16x16 pantry pantry

```
ASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
QJKAJ  KAKSJD  J
KJASDKFHI YOIER
W   OSDOFJ    DK
E PPPASP     AS
R
TASD 
YAAAAAAAAAAAA
U          JHOLK
IIAUSHODUYOAISUO
OASD  AUSODI 
PIASND JUASJNOIJ
A ASJDH PPOIO 
QHIAIUSOIUOOO
WYYAIUSNNAJSDASD
EAISDUUIOPJPIJPJ
ROQPEWIHRNXCAISD

QWERTYUIOP
----------------
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABCCDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDEEEEEFFFGHHHH
HHHIIIIIIIIIIIII
IIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJ
JJJJJJKKKKKKKKLL
MNNNNNNOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOPPPPPP
PPPPPPQQQQRRRRRS
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSTTUUUUUUUUUUU
UVWWY
```

## Test #5, 2x2 pantry

```
HE
LO

[no groceries]
--
HE
LO
```

Comment: why divide the program score?

Comment: I recommend you do count by bytes otherwise someone is just going to encode their entire program in Chinese characters and win.

Comment: @labela--gotoa To get a golfed score (smaller programs get a smaller score), should I change it?

Comment: @EphellonDantzler I don't understand why not just normal scoring...?

Comment: LOL, that's why I set in in Sandbox first @labela--gotoa

Comment: Some notes on your reference implementation: `1` It appears far too soon in the challenge. `2` It's not 1768 bytes. `3` You need to ungolf it and make it readable or it's not much use. `4` As it's JS, create a Snippet for it. `5` Is it necessary? It seems to be thrown in there to try to patch over any holes in the challenge spec.

Answer (score -1):

## Common Logic Gates

Given positive integer `n`, make a common `n`-to-1 gate with fewest input, i.e. make a function f: {0,1}<sup>k</sup> ↦ {0,1} with smallest `k` that, for each function g: {0,1}<sup>n</sup> ↦ {0,1}, there exists {a<sub>k</sub>}, such that each element a<sub>i</sub> in the sequence map to one of 0, 1, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, satisfying that, for each {x<sub>n</sub>}, g(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) = f(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>).

Samples:

To make a common 1-to-1 gate, your circuit must take at least 2 input:

```
f(A,B) = A XOR B
```

For a buffer gate (g = x<sub>1</sub> ↦ x<sub>1</sub>), let A=0 and B=Input (a<sub>1</sub> = 0, a<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>1</sub>); for a not gate (g = x<sub>1</sub> ↦ ¬x<sub>1</sub>) , let A=1 and B=Input (a<sub>1</sub> = 1, a<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>1</sub>).

Alternatively, you can use `f(A,B) = A AND NOT B`. For a buffer gate, let B=0 and A=Input; for a not gate, let A=1 and B=Input.

To make a common 2-to-1 gate, the circuit must take at least 4 input bits: (The two inputs are represented as `a` and `b`)

```
f(A,B,C,D) = ((A AND B) OR (C AND NOT B)) XOR D

(ab)
00 01 10 11 A B C D
0  0  0  1  a b 0 0
0  0  1  0  0 b a 0
0  1  1  0  a a a b
0  1  1  1  1 b a 0
1  0  0  0  1 b a 1
1  0  0  1  0 a 1 b
1  1  0  1  0 b a 1
1  1  1  0  a b 0 1
```

Output can be an boolean expression with reasonable logic gates, or just the output corresponding to all possible input of the `n`-to-1 function `f` (the truth table of `f`). If there are more than one possible functions, you can output any of them.

Shortest code in bytes win.

Code that matches the requirement:

```js
function solve(n) { // n positive int
    var res = [], tmp=[], inmap=[], need=[];
    for (var i=1; ; i++) {
        for (var _res=0; _res<2**(2**i); _res++) {
            var valid = 1;
            for (var j=0; j<2**i; j++)
                tmp[j] = Math.floor(_res/2**j)%2;
            for (var _need=0; _need<2**(2**n); _need++) {
                for (var j=0; j<2**n; j++) 
                    need[j] = Math.floor(_need/2**j)%2;
                var valid2 = 0;
                for (var _inmap=0; _inmap<(n+2)**i; _inmap++) {
                    var valid3 = 1;
                    for (var j=0; j<i; j++) 
                        inmap[j] = Math.floor(_inmap/(n+2)**j)%(n+2) - 1;
                    for (var j=0; j<2**n; j++) {
                        var bits = 0;
                        for (var k=0; k<i; k++) {
                            if (inmap[k]==-1 || (inmap[k] && (j>>(inmap[k]-1))%2))
                                bits |= 1 << k;
                        }
                        if (tmp[bits] != need[j]) 
                            valid3 = 0;
                    }
                    valid2 |= valid3;
                }
                if (!valid2) valid = 0;
            }
            if (valid) 
                res.push (tmp.slice());
        }
        if (res.length) 
            return res[AnyNonNegativeIntegerLessThan(res.length)];
        // binary index input
    }
}

function AnyNonNegativeIntegerLessThan(x) { if(R>=x) throw ("end"); return R;}
for (R=0; ; R++) { console.log (solve(1)); }
```

Comment: You don't define what an n-to-1 gate is anywhere in your question.

Comment: @user202729 @user56656 `n-to-1` gate means a gate with n input and 1 output. `common n-to-1 logic gate` mean a logic gate that can be used to replace any n-to-1 gate with some proper wiring. You can treat a logic gate as a ROM(so you can decide for each input what the output is)

Comment: Output gates or ROM

Comment: You should put the definitions in the challenge.  "that can be used to replace any n-to-1 gate with some proper wiring" is still not very clear, you should define more carefully what you mean by proper wiring.

Comment: I assume you mean functions `g: {0,1}^n -> {0,1}`, right? Why do you specify x_0 and x_-1? Shouldn't x just be a vector with indices 1,2,3,...,n?

Comment: Is {a_k} just a subset of {1,2,3,...,n}? Or can we have a_1=a_2=a_3=1 for example?

Comment: {a_k} seems not a multiset. It should be an array or say a sequence of numbers

Comment: So you're asking for something which outputs answers to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24983/194 ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No. it requires to use NAND gate to make up one circult that do the thing. Also 24983 is a 1-of-4 (74LS153), not a 4-to-1 gate common 2-to-1

Comment: (+) Any reason for downvoting? Downvoting in the sandbox indicates that the challenge is incomplete, if you don't leave a comment the OP can't know what is wrong.

Comment: @user202729, there are already comments indicating that this question is going to attract close votes as unclear if it's posted to main in the current state.

Comment: @user56656 Are the issues fixed now?

Comment: @flawr Are the issues fixed now?

Comment: No I still think the explanation is quite bad and the notation is not very clear

Comment: A reference implementation is no substitute for a clear specification. The first paragraph is where you need to focus your efforts.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Example not, but requirement yes

Comment: @flawr That's IMO not a constructive comment...

Comment: You asked for my opinion, and I think only the fact that we have to ask so many questions shows that the challenge as it is written now is very confusing. One example is the inconsistent notation. Another one the use of a negative index. This hides an important concept taht you do not only recombinate the arguments but you can also include these constants. If it is additionally not explicitly described what is going on without relying so heavily on these symbols I don't think it has any chance to succeed.

Comment: @flawr removed the negative indices

Answer (score -1):

## Interpret pseudocode

Wikipedia says pseudocode

> is intended for human reading rather than machine reading.

and

> A program in pseudocode is not an executable program.

I don't care.

Make a pseudocode interpreter that can run pseudocode that fits the rules described below*. This is based on the [IB pseudocode guide](http://ib.compscihub.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/IB-Pseudocode-rules.pdf), but it is simplified quite a bit to make it fit for the challenge.

---

## Pseudocode specifications

This is a simplified pseudocode to make the challenge less tedious. The pseudocode language has no strings, no arrays, no classes, no methods, and no variables other than integers.

### Basic syntax

Comments that start at `//` and end at a newline (like java one-line comments). `//` is not necessarily followed by a space, and the comment may be empty. Example:

```
A = 2 + 3 // I can't write five because my keyboard is broken
```

Statements are separated by newlines. Lines may be empty (without statements). The exact number of spaces doesn't matter, and spaces are not required. The language is case sensitive.

### Variables

All variables are global, and can be accessed anywhere. They do not need to be declared. To keep things simple, all variables can be assumed to be integers. All variable names are UPPERCASE, and consist only of letters. Your program should at least handle integers from -256 to 256. A wider range is not a requirement.

Variables are assigned values using this syntax:

```
VARIABLE = Expression
```

Where VARIABLE can be any uppercase name and expression can be any integer expression, as discussed below.

Examples:

```
A = 5
B = A + 3
NUMBER = A * B
```

### Expressions

An expression can be:

- An integer, like `42`
- A variable, like `NUMBER`
- A binary operation on two other expressions, like NUMBER + 5. There are only four operations: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. Division rounds integers down.

Expressions can be surrounded by parentheses to indicate that they need to be evaluated first. To keep things simple, all expressions are evaluated from left to right no matter what the operations are (unless there are parentheses that specify otherwise), so

```
A = 2 - RM * 9 + 3 / NUMBER
B = 1 + 2 * (3 - 4) / 6
```

is equivalent to

```
A = (((2 - RM) * 9) + 3) / NUMBER
B = ((1 + 2) * (3 - 4)) / 6
```

### Boolean expressions

Boolean expressions can compare two expressions using `==` (equality), `!=` (not equal to), `<` (less than), and `>` (greater than). They are only used for control flow, as discussed below (there are no boolean variables).

### Control flow

There are four types of control flow. They can be infinitely nested in all combinations.

#### If

```
if (booleanExpression) then
    // statements (discussed below)
endif
```

#### If-else

```
if (booleanExpression) then
    // statements (discussed below)
else
    // other statements
endif
```

#### Loop while

```
loop while (booleanExpression)
    // do stuff
endloop
```

Where `booleanExpression`s are boolean expressions. The `if`s work the same as in normal programming languages. The `while` loop is a simple while loop.

The booleanExpressions will always be surrounded by `()`. The pseudocode is very flexible with spaces, and any number of spaces is valid.

#### Loop for

```
loop VARIABLE from Expression1 to Expression2
    // things to do over and over again
end loop
```

Where `Expression1` and `Expression2` are expressions that are evaluated before the loop begins and their values are stored until the loop finishes. The content of the loop is executed for every integer from the result of `Expression1` to that of `Expression1`, inclusive. At every iteration, the index variable (`VARIABLE` in this case) is updated.

Example:

```
loop I from 3 to 5
    output(I)
endloop
```

Outputs:

```
3
4
5
```

### Statements

#### Output

`output(Expression)` outputs the evaluated expression. It's like `println` in programming languages. So:

```
output(1+1)
```

prints `2`, followed by a newline.

`output()` with no arguments should print a newline.

#### Other statements

If the interpreter encounters any other statement that looks like a method call with no arguments, it should pretend it's executing it. For example,

```
lightsoff()
gohome()
```

should print (together with a newline):

```
executing lightsoff
executing gohome
```

In other words, `executing [Method name]` should be printed. All statements will be lowercase and will consist entirely of letters.

Keywords cannot be statements. You do **not** have to deal with the following (it will not appear in the pseudocode):
- if()
- endif()
- loop()
- while()
- etc.

However, statements that start with keywords are valid. For example, loophole() should print `executing loophole`, even though `loop()` itself is not valid.

---

## Challenge rules

- Your program should take a string as input. It can also take something equivalent, like an array of characters. But you can't take an array of strings; your program must itself separate the lines and tokens. You can also take a file as input.
- Your program should print the output of the pseudocode in any reasonable form.
- No standard loopholes.
- There are no restrictions on what your program should do when given invalid pseudocode.
- This is code golf. The shortest code in bytes wins.

---

## Example output

## 1

```
A = 3
output(A) // prints 3
B = 4 + A * 2
output(B)
helloworld()
output(A + B + 1 * 3)
```

Should give:

```
3
14
executing helloworld
54
```

## 2

```
loop NUM from 2 to 20 // cycle through possible prime numbers
    COUNT = 0
    loop DIV from 2 to NUM // cycle through possible divisors
        if(NUM/DIV*DIV == NUM) then // if the number is exactly divisible
            COUNT = COUNT + 1
        endif
    endloop
    if (COUNT == 2) then // if number is prime
        output(NUM)
    endif
endloop
```

Should give:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
```

## 3

Tricky cases that your interpreter should handle:

```
// empty comment:
//
// empty line:

    // more comment testing // ///
////

if     (3<4) then
    endoftheworld() // a statement
    ifff()
    endifnot()
    // endif in a comment doesn't count
endif
// loops can be empty:
loop I from 0 to 10
endloop
output(I) // variables are global
if(1<2)
    if(3<4) // nesting is ok
        ok()
    endif
endif
// spacing doesn't matter:
output   (2+   8   - 1   )
loop             while(2<1)
    neverhappened()
endloop
```

Should output:

```
executing endoftheworld
executing ifff
executing endifnot
10
excecuting ok
9
```

<sub>*Technically, once pseudocode follows rules as strict as those described here, it is arguably not pseudocode anymore. Wikipedia says it's called skeleton code.</sub>

---

Any suggestions?

I double-checked all the specifications, but if anything seems reasonably unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Actually that's because the challenge is uninteresting.

Comment: @Akangka thanks for the feedback. How do you think it could be made more interesting?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing to improve. You have to find other challenge. Also, it is not pseudo-code.

Comment: @Ok, thanks. I'll try to think of something. Also, read the *note. :)

Answer (score -1):

## Is the program 32 or 64 bits?

Assignment is simple to explain: write the shortest code you need to determine whether an executable binary program supplied as parameter is 32 or 64 bits.

If there is a different kind of bitness, you can also do for it, but is not mandatory.

What I really don't want is telling me you support other bitnesses and after I get 32 or 64 as a result.

Valid outputs for 32:

```
32
32bit
32bits
32 bit
32 bits
```

The same pattern for 64.

No accepted answer.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [x86-family](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x86-family)

Comment: I think you're missing a word somewhere in the region of "determine supplied"

Comment: @KamilDrakari thanks.

Comment: Executable on Windows or Linux machine? What if (... maybe ...) the program is a valid executable for both "bitness" but do different things?

Comment: Of the output formats you allow, I think the first one will result in the shortest code in every single language. Because of this, you might as well just specify that the output should be the number 32 or the number 64.

Comment: This made me wonder what to do about shell scripts, which are executable programs, but require another file to interpret them and as such aren't 32-bit or 64-bit per se. Maybe it would be best to specify "executable binary file" to not have to deal with that mess.

Comment: @Angs: Thanks. Changed.

Comment: @user202729: I don't care. Windows, Linux, Mac, whatever, ...

Comment: @Nathaniel: It is intentional. If you have a language feature called `bitness(program)` returning `32bits` you do not need to waste more bytes removing the `bits` part!

Comment: The word "challenge" is not really true, at least for ELF. It's absolutely trivial.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : Changed, thanks.

Comment: The real "challenge" is to know the executable file format, so this becomes more of a puzzle than a challenge. And for puzzles, people can just copy others' solution and port to other languages. // Consider having some popular file format in the challenge itself so people don't have to look up them?

Comment: @user202729: My initial idea was to ask only for Windows .exe files but I changed my mind because it was too limiting. Without such restrictions the question becomes multi-platform.

Answer (score -1):

## Introduction

I recently came across an oral exam where the candidates were asked to find a logical circuit than can negate 3 inputs A,B,C using only two `NOT` gates.

The question also specified that such a circuit is unique up to removal of useless gates and reordering inputs/outputs. The candidates were asked to prove this assertion by writing a piece of code that generates all such circuits.

## Challenge

No inputs whatsoever are given.

The program must output all logical circuits using unlimited `AND` and `OR` gates but only two `NOT` gates which take in three inputs which map to three outputs. The outputs should be the negation of each input.

The outputted circuits should not have any redundant/trivial gates (gates that always output the same thing) or unused gates (whose output doesn't influence the outcome).

The program should use as little precalculated data as possible.

Output format is left up to the coders.

The winner will be determined by overall simplicity -- low run time and code elegance. It is not an objective criterion.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> N/A

Output:

```
R    = (A & B) | (A & C) | (B & C)
notR = !R
S    = (notR & (A | B | C)) | (A & B & C)
notS = !S

notA = (notR & notS) | (notR & S & (B | C)) | (R & notS & (B & C))
notB = (notR & notS) | (notR & S & (A | C)) | (R & notS & (A & C))
notC = (notR & notS) | (notR & S & (A | B)) | (R & notS & (A & B))
```

Comment: Example output and proof of existence are provided [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98308/can-i-get-the-not-of-3-inputs-using-as-many-and-or-gates-but-only-2-not-gates)

Comment: "*It is not an objective criterion.*" Then it is not an on-topic question.

Answer (score -1):

## Projective related points

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Points `A, B, C, D` and `A′, B′, C′, D′` are related by a projective transformation if their cross ratios are equal.

[image: Projective related points]

Given `A, B, C, D` four ordered points on a line, their cross ratio is defined as:

\$\displaystyle\frac{distance(A,C)\times distance(B,D)}{distance(A,D)\times distance(B,C)}\$,

where \$distance(A,C)\$ is the Euclidean distance between points A and C.

### Challenge

Given a set of eight points, say if yes or no the set can be splited into two subgroups (each subgroup with four points) where the two subgroups are related by a projective transformation.

### Input

A set of 8 points, each point defined by its Cartesian coordinates (integer coordinates).

### Output

Either a specific true output (true, 1, yes, ...) or a specific false output (false, 0, no, ...).

### Example

```
{(10,100),(25,100),(2,63),(2,33),(31,100),(2,13),(2,3),(17,100)} --> true
with subgroups:
{(10,100),(25,100),(31,100),(17,100)} 
and 
{(2,63),(2,33),(2,13),(2,3)}

{(45,54),(8,23),(8,8),(8,29),(27,30),(15,14),(9,6),(8,15)} --> true
with subgroups:
{(8,23),(8,8),(8,29),(8,15)}
and 
{(45,54),(27,30),(15,14),(9,6)}
```

### Hint (no need to use division or square root)

In order to avoid floating points, you can use the fact that points `A, B, C, D` and `A′, B′, C′, D′` are related by a projective transformation implies:

\$distance^2(A,C)\times distance^2(B,D)\times distance^2(A',D')\times distance^2(B',C')\$

equals

\$distance^2(A',C')\times distance^2(B',D')\times distance^2(A,D)\times distance^2(B,C)\$

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- No need to output the two subgroups.
- No need to handle the case when at least two points in the set are the same.
- No need to check the fact that the four points in each subgroup are aligned.
- In your submission, please state the true and the false values.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an on-line testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: As with most problems involving floating point comparisons, I think you should include a  large-ish number of test cases and require that submissions pass all of those cases. That way people can be sure their submissions are sufficiently accurate.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman In fact there is a way to work only with integers, I'll add a hint.

Comment: I had totally missed that the input would always be integers. Cary on, but I still recommend including at least several test cases to make users more able to be sure their submission works without having to find edge cases on their own.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ok I'll add more examples.

Comment: Is the cross ratio \$\overline{AC}\times\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{AD}}\times\overline{BC}\$ or \$\frac{\overline{AC}\times\overline{BD}}{\overline{AD}\times\overline{BC}}\$?

Comment: @wastl it's the second one, thanks for the remark, I just updated the formula.

Answer (score -1):

## Two functions with same input/output, with largest difference in bytes.

***This challenge is a terrible idea. Don't try submitting it or anything similar!***

Provide two ***functions*** with the largest difference in bytes. (These two ***functions*** will be referred to in bold italics to distinguish them from built-in functions available in your language in the rules below.)

Rules:

1. Both ***functions*** must take an input and must produce an output. The input to and output from both ***functions*** must be identical.
2. Both ***functions*** must be explicitly named. The ***function*** names must have the same byte count.
3. You may not define any other functions.
4. If you use a built-in function your language provides, it must be used with the same number of parameters in each of the ***functions***.
5. You may use string/numeric literals or any built-in constants, but you must use exactly the same ones in both ***functions***.
6. You can define variables, must you must use the same variable names in both ***functions***.
7. You can use comments, no-ops, and the equivalent, but they must be the same in both ***functions***.
8. Both ***functions*** must contain the same amount of whitespace (or equivalently, don't count whitespace at all.)
9. You can import libraries/packages and the equivalent, as long as you import the same ones for both ***functions***.
10. You can use pre-processor directives as long as they are the same for both ***functions***.

If any of these rules mean your language cannot compete, so be it.

Not really sure how to tag this. A little bit of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) and [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source).

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. {Main downvote}

Comment: Give up. E.g. in APL, `⊢` and `⊢⊢⊢⊢⊢⊢⊢⊢`…`⊢` do the same.

Comment: @Adám, with those rules, it'd be something like `f←⊢` and `g←⊢(⊢(⊢(⊢(...))))` due to rules #2 and #3. The same thing still applies to OP: give up!

Comment: Thank you. I am happy to give up!

Comment: @Zacharý I intended them to be dyadic, but whatever…

Comment: "Both functions must take an input", which I assume would restrict the functions to monadic.

Answer (score -1):

Quiet QR

Your mission, should you choose to accept it is to infiltrate the top secret HQ of the Big Bad Evil Guy (TM) and extract information on their latest evil scheme saved in the file Plan.txt.

The target PC is isolated from any and all network connections, and you can't physically connect anything to it. The server room is equipped with sound sensors that will detect key presses.

Your tools are restricted to a mobile phone equipped with a QR code reader.
Your recommended course of action is to write a code on the target machine that will display the file content as QR code.

You are to complete the mission with the least number of keystrokes as to minimise the sound generated by the mechanical keyboard.
It is advisable not to use languages that require unicode characters as entering one character will require multiple key presses (Eg:þ = Alt+0254) is considered 5 keystrokes.

You are to assume that the machine will have its terminal open and ready for input at the root directory of the system (C:\> or /).

All programming languages can be accessed directly from root folder.
The target file is on the root folder.

Javascript is available as command line executable named js usable as (js filename) and prints output.

Image viewer is called view and usable as (view imagefile) [Extension is not needed]

Possible ways of output:

1. An image containing the QR code
2. ASCII art depicting the QR code using characters like █ ▄▀
3. Or any form readable by any standard-issue QR code reader
4. Other formats of 2D barcodes are accepted on the condition of being readable by a standard reader.

Example Solution for batch file:

```
copy con a.bat
open file Plan.txt
echo █ ▄▀
^Z
a
```

=59 keystrokes.

The symbols are 4 keystrokes each:

- ▀ Alt+991
- █ Alt+987
- ▄ Alt+988

^Z as Ctrl+z and is considered 2 ketstrokes (F6 is considered one).
New lines and spaces are one keystroke each.
Capital letters are 2 strokes (Shift+c).
CAPITAL words are one keystroke added to the length of the word (Shift+capital).
No need to clean the screen at the end because the evidence will be erased by a Micro-EMP device that will disable the machine.

Comment: Why not just have a question to turn text into a QR code? The keystroke golfing just seems to complicate things

Comment: @JoKing The premise of the challenge is to extract information from a pc with the least keystrokes.

Comment: In that case, what operating system is the PC? What type of QR code do you want (alphanumeric or byte?)? Can you add a link or explain an algorithm to generate you type of QR code (questions should be self-contained)? How big can the input be (100 bytes? 1kb?), and what characters can it contain?

Comment: You may assume that the PC have an open terminal window ready for input in whatever OS you'd want (Bash, PowerShell, Command prompt,.....) The QR code must be able to encode alphanumeric+punctuation text in the file Plan.txt

Answer (score -1):

A function to traverse an array and re-generate the same array

We take an array, then write a function that will traverse the array and generate the array in a format given in the example below.

**For example, given the array:**

```
Array

(

  [0] => Array
  ( [name] => Tom
      [age] => 32
      [key] => Array
      ( [0] => abc
          [1] => def
          [2] => efg
          )
      )
  [1] => Array
  ( [name] => Jim
      [age] => 30
      [key] => Array
      ( [0] => abc
          [1] => def
          [2] => efg
          )
      [address] => Array
      ( [0] => Array
          ( [state] => CA
              [country] => US
              )
          [1] => Array
          ( [state] => NY
              [country] => US
              )
          )
     )
)
```

**Output should be:**

```
User: 0
 name: Tom
 age: 32
 key:
  0: abc
  1: def
  2: efg
User: 1
 name: Jim
 age: 30
 key:
  0: abc
  1: def
  2: efg
address:
0:
 state: CA
 country: US
1:
 state: NY
 country: US
```

**Challenge rules:**

- You can assume array can be `multidimensional`
- The array can also be array of `cars`, `schools`, `districts` etc.
- The preferred output is in json format
- Indentation for the output is a simple json format

`code-golf`

The function will be tested with any sort of `multidimensional` arrays for speed of execution

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation of how you generated the array? For example, where does `Name` come from, and what are the rules behind indentation?

Comment: The array just contains User details which will include the `Name`, `Age`, `Address` etc.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to PPCG. We usually require challenges to be a bit more precisely defined, to avoid ambiguity. For eg., you mention " generate the array in a format given in the example below", and the rules say "the preferred output is in json format" - but the format in the example is not JSON (and has some possible issues, for eg. `address` not being indented). Also, the post says "array" throughout, but what you're actually working with looks like a nested hashmap/dictionary structure.

Comment: Finally, you've mentioned [tag:code-golf], but also that the answers will be tested for speed of execution - do you intend code-golf (number of bytes) to be the primary winning criterion and the speed of execution the tie-breaker? Or do you mean all answers have to transform a particular large input within a certain time (say 1 minute) to be valid? In the latter case, it would be useful to specify what the large, multidimensional input will be, and what the maximum time of execution allowed is.

Answer (score -1):

## Pyramid of Bots

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

In this game, your bot is trying to get as high off the ground as possible. However, it can only stand on top of other bots, which are trying to get higher, too!

### Overview

Your bot should be a Javascript function. It's return value should tell the program if the bot should move left, move right, or jump. Every bot starts out on a 2 dimensional grid, with a width and height set by `(botCount * 2) + 1`. Bots are placed on either side of the center space, and every other bot is spaced 1 apart from any other bot. They all start at `y=0`, and far left is `x=0`.

### Gravity

If there is no bot on top of your bot, it can return the value `jump`. When a bot jumps, it moves 1 square up. If at any point in time there is nothing under the bot, it moves down 1. A bot cannot return `jump` if nothing is under it. If your bot is on top of another bot which moves left, your bot will fall.

### Function params

Your function has 3 parameters: `dirs`, `height`, and `map`. The array `dirs` contains four boolean values, representing if there is a bot or arena border: below, to left, to right, above. The parameter `height` is an array with 2 elements: your height, current winner's height. The `map` array contains the height/width of the array, and then the amount of turns left in the game.

### Running the game

In one game, the bot function will be run 800 times. Each of these is a turn. Your bot should return `jump`, or a direction. The bot can only move in a direction if there is no bot currently there. The two directions are `left` and `right`. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed (when are they ever allowed??), and the bot who wins the most out of 1000 games is the winner.

Comment: I don't see the strategy in this.  There's *no* way for a bot to reliably move up.  No bot will stand still, so you literally have to guess whether or not an adjacent bot will move under you, and then hope that they move up while other adjacent bots move under.

Answer (score -1):

## My Ribosomes Got a Firmware Upgrade

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [bioinformatics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)

---

So all of the Apple iBosomes in my body have been updated to RibOS 4.0 now… while I appreciate the additional optimizations that were added, unfortunately for me they've dropped support for the legacy mRNA API.

So since my RNA Polymerase library still needs to return strings in the format `AUUCGGUCAAAGU` for the code still using it, I'll need to add some code to the `getBasePairs()` method to translate it from the new API.

## Challenge

- Your input will be a string in base64 (because codons are exactly 6 bits) representing the genome.
- You should *output* a string with the equivalent RNA base pair sequence:

  - `00` becomes `A`.
  - `01` becomes `G`.
  - `10` becomes `C`.
  - `11` becomes `U`.
- All languages are allowed.
- Your I/O must be in these exact string formats, even if they're small enough to encode as integers.
- The shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Are you asking for a method that does a base64 to base4 conversion and pretty-prints the result?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Kinda, I guess.

Comment: So using lax I/O I can take the input as an integer and output four unique values [like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqiqzQCMpM08jTzPayMrKKFYHyjEGcTT/FxRl5pVo5GQWl2ikaZgYG1kaWGhqav4HAA)?

Comment: @JonathanFrech wasn't what I had in mind; I'll edit the proposal once I finish the essay I'm working on right now.

Answer (score -1):

**Trilateration**

Intro:

Similar to [Trilaterate your position](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75791/trilaterate-your-position) with a small twist.

In a n x m array,

Original Problem:

You will be given a list of (x,y,d) as input,
where d is the distance of your position from the point (x,y).
Using this we can find our position.

................

In the above problem, d is the exact distance from the respective point.

In this problem, due to some error, we know that the distance is actually the maximum distance from the respective point. Because of that, instead of a single point, we will get a small area of our position. Objective is to get that area.

It should be in the format(a function):

```
f(list,n,m):
  #your code here
  return #list of all indices where you may be.
```

What's returning should be a list of points (x,y) with 0<=x<=n,0<=y<=m.

In case there is no solution return an empty list.
The winner will be the fastest code.
In case of a tie shorter code wins.
The time taken will most likely depend on n,m and list of points.

Comment: On which test(s) will the code be measured?

Comment: Edited it.. Also, what are the tags I should add other then fastest-algorithm

Answer (score -1):

The goal of this challenge is to make an interpreted language that can print anything! The format of the language needs to be

```
[command eg: print] [args];
```

You have to use regex, even though it is not the typical way to write a language, to avoid people finding loopholes. Your interpreter also needs to ask for a file to open to interpret; example input file prompt:"File to interpret: "

Some tests to try:

```
print Hello World;


print This is a very very very very very long test;

ktrgjkfgjk;

print hi
```

If your interpreter runs these tests correctly, you can submit your interpreter.

## Notes:

**Do not just cut off the print!**

**If the command given does not exist, or if semicolon not present, print "Error"**

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the **lowest byte count + working code wins!**

Comment: I recommend some more explanation of the "File: " part

Comment: @trichoplax Thats the input file prompt

Comment: @trichoplax, well then i wont accept those answers, hold on let me edit

Comment: Read it again: it says: The format of the language needs to be

[command eg: print] [args]; <--- note semicolon It was just a typo (I didnt type the ;)

Comment: The problem with saying "do not just cut off the print" is that there may be other ways of achieving the same thing, then the challenge just becomes a long list of things which are banned. You can avoid this by trying to set the requirements and inputs in a way that doesn't have these loopholes.

Comment: @trichoplax Ok i only want the print though

Comment: Writing challenges can be tricky, and people have posted advice on meta that can help: [things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges) and [things to consider when creating a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/things-to-consider-when-creating-a-challenge?rq=1)

Comment: If you only want print, then is there a difference between this challenge and "remove the first 6 characters and the last character from this string"? If you don't want people to solve it that way, you could consider what they need to do when the input is not a valid print command, and specify that in that case it should do something different (like not output anything).

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, i didnt think of that

Comment: "do not just cut off the print" is an example of a non-observable requirement. [Here's a good explanation of why that can be a problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20283)

Comment: Here, new update

Comment: I hope all the comments don't put you off - writing challenges is difficult, but we get much more answers than challenges so more challenges are needed. I had lots of useful feedback from this community when I started out.

Comment: Is this better @trichoplax and where else can i improve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84156/discussion-between-menotdan-and-trichoplax).

Comment: That's all I have time for at the moment. We usually recommend leaving posts in the sandbox for a few days to get more feedback from more people.

Comment: `you have to use regex ... , to avoid people finding loopholes` This seems very arbitrairly restricting. What about languages without regexes? You haven't actually said what the outputs of the test are. And what exactly is the program meant to have as input? I recommend a string input instead of messing around with files

Answer (score -1):

### Name: Create a Programming Language

### Tags: code-bowling, and cops-and-robbers

## Cops:

The cops must design a programming language that takes in the contents of the program from a default I/O method, and do something.

**Rules:**

- The program must not print anything to STDERR
- The program must be able to output to STDOUT with certain program contents of your choice
- The program must be able to calculate any function up to \$f_{\omega}(n)\$ where f is the [fast-growing hierarchy](https://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy). In other words, it needs to be able to evaluate any primitive-recursive statement.
- There cannot be a way to execute commands in other languages (for example, if there is a command in your programming language that can execute Python code based on the argument, that would be cheating)

Since there are tons of loopholes, whether or not the answer is valid is up to me (and also, standard loopholes are also not allowed).

## Robbers:

Your job is to make the same compiler (which does the same thing with the same commands given as the equivalent cop answer), with more characters. The programming language may be different.

Standard loopholes aren't allowed, and whether an answer is valid or not will be judged by me.

**As always, since this is code-bowling, aim for the most bytes!**

Comment: "whether or not the answer is valid is up to me" unfortunately, this is going to make the challenge unclear.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the core of this challenge. The robbers have to make the compiler larger without affecting its functionality? That seems trivial to do; just add a comment or some whitespace.

Comment: `Your job is to make the same compiler ... with more characters` Should this be *less* characters? also, shouldn't it be bytes?

Comment: @JoKing Yeah, I realized that.

Answer (score -1):

## Win 2048

Win 2048. You can decide where to summon block of 2(no 4), and how you move. The output would be [place, place, move, place, move, ..., place, move](finally you reach 2048).

Shortest code win.

SN: Similar to [Play a perfect game of 2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/27010) ?

Comment: (in case somebody don't understand the challenge: the program should take no input, and output any sequence of moves in 2048 game such that the tile 2048 is generated. As said in the challenge, the new block must be [2] (not [4]) and the program can determine where the block appears)

Answer (score -1):

#### Coprimes upto N (Performance Edition)

There is this question: [Coprimes up to N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/coprimes-up-to-n)

Most of the answers there take way to long for larger numbers.

So, your task is to find all the coprimes of a number `n`  (`gcd(n,coprime)==1`) up to `n`as fast as possible.

#### Scoring

Score=Largest `n` for which your code will output in less than 10 seconds on my laptop. Provide instructions to run it on my machine.

Highest score wins.

*I will put the specs of my pc, anything else needed?*

Comment: I think this is not interesting. The output (φ(n) numbers) is too large in comparison with the time complexity of a reasonably-competitive algorithm (I'd expect algorithms to take n log n time at worst), so printing output is going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: What if I make it to print the number of coprimes instead? @user202729

Comment: That is number of primes @user202729. This is co-primes of n.

Comment: Still, very similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26739/super-speedy-totient-function .

Answer (score -1):

## A Quine that Grows!

**Challenge**

Create a quine that, when run, outputs itself but copied larger in the next one. The output should be able to be run, and get larger each time the output is run. **The output must consist only of characters from the original quine!**

EX:

```
abc //original
abcabc //output
```

**or**

```
abc //original
aabcc //output
```

**What not to do**

```
abc //original
abcgef //output

abc //original
abcoooooooooooo //output
```

**An example I created**

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X9nDW9cop1ZJ/f9/AA)
It replicates pretty fast if I do say so myself!

**Points**

This challenge is meant to be a codegolf, but also emphasize on how fast it replicates. So perhaps something like the speed at which it gets bigger divided by the number of bytes.

I really don't want loopholes like just repetitively adding characters to a section of the code, making infinite loops, and things of the like.

Any input on how to make this a good challenge? I'm open to suggestions!!!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/158429/76162), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21831/76162) (probably a dupe)

Comment: @JoKing What about a polyglot that gets bigger? It runs, making another program that runs and outputs a bigger version of the original, and vice versa.

Comment: where's the polyglot part come from? otherwise that sounds like the second one

Comment: @JoKing The output has to be in a different programming language, and then create a larger version of the original, then this larger original makes a larger of second program etc... Also to prevent easy loopholes, no using program languages that are derivatives of eachother

Answer (score -1):

Just idea. Not sure what to do exactly.

## Evolutionary Golf

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) [restricted-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-code)

Make simple (not golfed at all at first) code for *(some program)* with language *(something)*.

Now, change a little bit (maximum 3 byte) of code to make it shorter.

Altered code must work properly (this is how evolution work).

(Maybe here will be starting code).

#### Sandbox

First. What program would be best? For example, 'Hello World' program is not proper, because it is too short, and can't golf that much.

Second. What language would be best? Esolang like BF? Or something like C?

Comment: If I understand the challenge idea correctly you will post an ungolfed answer that does something in some (probably verbose) language (i.e. FizzBuzz in C#). And then answers after that should have a Levensteihn distance change \$c\$ where \$1\leq c\leq3\$ (at least 1 delete) that does the same thing (in any language). And the shortest answer that's at the end of the answer chain wins if no other answers are posted within 2-3 weeks (which is usually the case with answer-chaining challenges)? Or do you mean that anyone can post an ungolfed program, and others using the same language chain it?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm thinking of both. This is just brief outline, so everything can be changed.

Comment: this is just game of nim with extra steps

Answer (score -1):

## Print all the commands

**META** Just a rought idea, needs to be worked out.
[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a program that prints all the keywords and commands that are available in your langauge when you do not import/add anything

#### Details

- require full program or standard code-golf?

Comment: Understanding that this is a rough idea, what happens in languages without commands corresponding to single tokens e.g. ///?

Comment: It is my opinion that this sort of challenge will likely never be clear.

Comment: I'd imagine for /// you'd output all valid non-text characters, so `\ /`.

Comment: Another thing is that language version would be specified. For example, Python 2 has `print` as a keyword, while Python 3 has `print()` instead.

Comment: Pretty sure this (or something similar enough to be a dupe) has been done before. Lemme see if I can find it ....

Comment: Found it! https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162384/58974

Comment: One way to do this might be to make it language specific? While that isn't usually popular, outputting all of, say, Python's commands in most languages besides python is a dupe of the Rickroll challenge. However, in python itself that isn't the best approach.  I can't say how well reveived it'd be, but you could try "output these MATLAB commands in MATLAB" and see what people think.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a challenge I'd like post because I'm curious to see what people will come up with. It's a bit of an anti-code-golf question because the code should look normal.

Is it clear what the constraints? Did I miss anything?

---

## Introduction

Write a piece of **unsuspicious** code that does the following:

Let's say you've written a parser that parses it's input line by line and somewhere in your code is

```
find_string(line, "[start]", "[end]") // returns string between [start] and [end]
```

This program, when given it's own source code plain text as input, will match that line (twice actually); but we don't want that. It should still parse what it was designed for but not match any line of it's own source code.

## Rules

- It's preferred that your code makes it obvious that one of it's intended uses is to parse (and not match) itself. This is so anyone 'refactoring' the code will not accidentally undo the trick that made it work.
- Your source code as input will be reduced to a single line.
- Your program should be able to handle large input (~10mb) and perform reasonably (for your chosen language).
- Your program does not need to parse the input line by line but that just seems like something reasonable code would do.
- Points are awarded for code that looks like a normal parser and contains as little assumptions about the input as possible. Bonus points for solutions that contain the `start` and `end` delimiters in that order.

Easy solutions are to swap the start and end token arguments or to pre-treat the tokens in some way but that would look suspicious. Someone will come along and refactor your code and break the 'trick'.

I'm interested in reasonable solutions because this is a reduction of a real life problem.

## Example Input and Output

- Input lines may or may not contain `[start]` or `[end]`, only return it in the output when it occurs in a pair.
- Input lines will never contain more than one pair of `[start]` and `[end]` tokens.
- Input lines may contain additional content before `[start]` or after `[end]`
- Your source code plain text will be inserted at a random line in the input.

Input #1:

```
[start]hello[end]
<<your source code plain text>>
dont output this[start]world[end]
```

Output #1:

```
hello world
```

Input #2:

```
lorem[start]i solemnly[end]
[start]false start
[start]swear[end]
ope, sorry just passing through
this is not the[end]
[start]that i'm up to[end]ipsum
[start]no[end]dolor
<<your source code plain text>>
[start]good[end]
```

Output #2:

```
i solemnly swear that i'm up to no good
```

Comment: What is the objective winning criterion?

Comment: This could be a good challenge if it was just 'Write a program that takes a line of input and returns the concatenation of anything between `[start]` and `[end]` on each line, otherwise an empty string', with the restriction that if it was fed itself, it wouldn't return anything

Comment: I'm a little confused about what `Bonus points for solutions that contain the start and end delimiters in that order.` means, since I thought the point was that we're not allowed to have that?

Comment: "***unsuspicious** code*" will raise red flags in the minds of a number of old-timers, for historical reasons which I won't explain in detail. What I will say is that *unsuspicious* is subjective, and we insist on objective criteria. In terms of actual reasonable solutions to the real world problem: don't use magic strings. If "[start]" and "[end]" are both constants and defined on separate lines, the problem is averted, and anyone who refactors to inline them deserves all the bugs that causes.

Answer (score -1):

**Title: Transposition**

** The challenge **

Given a set of notes (as a string, or a list, or any other reasonable input - but as letters and accidentals, not a numerical equivalent), the key those notes are in, and a target key; output the notes transposed into the new key. Some of the notes may not exist in the scale for the given key (e.g Eb in the key of C).

** Inputs **

The complete set of input notes for this challenge will use the English naming convention, and so are as follows:

`Ab,G##,A,A#,Bb,B,C,C#,Db,C##,D,D#,Eb,E,F,F#,Gb,F##,G,G#`

where "b" represents a flattened note (down one semitone per `b`), and # represents a sharpened note (up one semitone per `#`). Theoretically all notes can be extended further with more #s and bs; but for the purposes of this program that won't happen beyond what is already given.

** What is transposing? **

Transposing a song involves "moving" the song into a different key, by finding the equivalent note of the scale in that key.

We will assume Major scales for the purposes of this challenge.

** Scales **

The scales for this challenge are officially as follows:

- `C`: C, D, E, F, G, A, B, C
- `C#`: C#, D#, E#, F#, G#, A#, B#, C#
- `Db`: Db, Eb, F, Gb, Ab, Bb, C, Db
- `D`: D, E, F#, G, A, B, C#, D
- `D#`: D#, E#, F##, G#, A#, B#, C##, D#
- `Eb`:Eb, F, G, Ab, Bb, C, D, Eb
- `E`: E, F#, G#, A, B, C#, D#, E
- `F`: F, G, A, Bb, C, D, E, F
- `F#`: F#, G#, A#, B, C#, D#, E#, F#
- `Gb`: Gb, Ab, Bb, Cb, Db, Eb, F, Gb
- `G`: G, A, B, C, D, E, F#, G
- `G#`: G#, A#, B#, C#, D#, E#, F##, G#
- `Ab`: Ab, Bb, C, Db, Eb, F, G, Ab
- `A`: A, B, C#, D, E, F#, G#, A
- `A#`: A#, B#, C##, D#, E#, F##, G##, A#
- `Bb`: Bb, C, D, Eb, F, G, A, Bb
- `B`: B, C#, D#, E, F#, G#, A#, B

For simplicity, we can assume that both notes in the pairs A#/Bb, C#/Db, D#/Eb, F#/Gb, G#/Ab, C##/D, F##/G, G##/A are enharmonically equivalent (i.e. interchangeable - [although they're not, always](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11815/what-is-the-difference-between-sharp-note-flat-note)).

For scales with double-sharps, I will accept the enharmonic equivalents as an alternative implementation:

- `D#`: D#, E#, `G`, G#, A#, B#, `D`, D#
- `G#`: G#, A#, B#, C#, D#, E#, `G`, G#
- `A#`: A#, B#, `D`, D#, E#, `G`, `A`, A#

but for all other notes in the scale, they must match. If the note isn't in the scale, either can be used.

e.g.

- `F` in the key of `C` should transpose to `F#` in the key of `C#`, and not to `Gb`, because that option in the pair is explicitly in the scale
- but `D` in the key of `C#` could transpose to either `C#` or `Db` in the key of `C`, because it's an incidental anyway and so there's no easy rule to determine which it should be.

*BONUS feel-good points* *: normally it's `#` if you're going up, and a `b` if you're going down - feel free to implement this if you want!

For double-sharps (e.g `F##`) in all cases, It's OK if the program "resolves" these (e.g.to `G` in that case) even if they are in the scale; but again, some *BONUS feel-good points* * if you keep the double-sharps in.

**Examples**

- `CDEFGABC` in `C` to `A` -> `ABC#DEF#G#A`
- `C#` in `C` to `A` -> `A#` OR `Bb`
- `ABCDEFGBAF#Bb` in `Bb` to `Gb` -> `FGAbBbCDbEbGFDGb`
- `CCGGAAAAGFFEEDDCGGGFFEEEDCGGGFFFFEEED` in `C` to `G#` -> `G#G#D#D#E#E#E#E#D#C#C#B#B#A#A#G#D#D#D#C#C#B#B#B#A#G#D#D#D#C#C#C#C#B#B#B#A#`

Websites like http://www.logue.net/xp/ can be used to test your answers to other inputs

`*` *Bonus feel-good points don't get you anything extra, unless someone can come up with a quantifiable difference that it should make to the score?*

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3847/31625) is kind of similar but doesn't use scales and has a different set of chords, so I think this is effectively different?

Comment: Yes, I agree it's similar but doing a different thing to me (they're using chords, and so have the extra text to worry about; but I'm doing notes, like sheet music; and so you have accidentals to worry about)

Answer (score -1):

## Mirror, Mirror, on the wall. Who's the fairest of them all?

Well, you know it's Snow White, and the evil Queen is at it again. Will Snow White be saved? Will she fall asleep once again? Will the Prince find her?

## Challenge:

Given an arbitrary number (>= 2) of possibly duplicated hexadecimal color values (ranging from #000000 to #FFFFFF) and paired strings, calculate the following:

- If #FF0800 (Candy apple red) appears in the input, return "Return to Sleeping Death"
- If #000000 appears in the input, return "Saved by Grumpy"
- If #A98AC7 or #111111 appears in the input, return "Saved by Happy"
- If #21E88E or #222222 appears in the input, return "Saved by Sleepy"
- If #32DCD5 or #333333 appears in the input, return "Saved by Bashful"
- If #43D11C or #444444 appears in the input, return "Saved by Sneezy"
- If #54C563 or #555555 appears in the input, return "Saved by Dopey"
- If #65B9AA or #666666 appears in the input, return "Saved by Doc"
- If #76ADF1 or #777777 appears in the input, return "Saved by the Seven Dwarfs"
- If #FFFAFA (Snow) appears in the input, return "Saved by Love's first kiss"
- If an F variant appears in the input, return "Press F to pay respects to Snow White"

  - An F variant is any number that contains at least one `F` in its hexadecimal form, and is otherwise all `0`s (e.g. #0FF0F0, #FFFFFF, #00000F, #F00F00)
- If **multiple** of the preceding occur, return the "fairest" answer. The "fairest" answer is calculated as follows:

  - For all N occurrences of special color values, choose the (N-1)/2-th (truncating division) occurrence. The associated special output is the "fairest" answer.

*"Appears in the input" here refers to only the hexadecimal color values, and not to the paired strings.*

- If none of the preceding occur, return the "fairest" answer. The "fairest" answer is calculated as follows:

  - Take the hexadecimal color value at the end of input values, write it down, and exclude that single color-string pair from consideration as the "fairest" answer
  - Show its binary form to the mirror, computing a reflection of only the last 24 (#FFFFFF is the mask) bits.
  - Choose the hexadecimal color with least Hamming distance from the reflection. If there are multiple (N) such colors, choose the middle ((N-1)/2-th, truncating division) instance of the color. The "fairest" answer is the associated string for the color.

## Inputs:

A sequence of hexadecimal color values and String values separated by a space. The input may also be read as two separate sequences of hexadecimal color values and String values, or a single sequence of 2-tuples (either `(hexValue, stringValue)` or `(stringValue, hexValue)` is permissible, as long as the ordering is consistent across all 2-tuples).  Input order matters - for each index, the corresponding element in the supply of color values is "associated" with the corresponding element in the supply of String values, and duplicates can affect the "fairest" answer. The effect is something like `Function(List(HexColorValue),List(AssociatedStrings)) -> "fairest" answer`. Hexadecimal color values may be represented as either (your choice of) a String "#"+6 digits, or 6 digits alone, as long as the representation is consistent across all color values.

Here's an example input:

```
76ADF1 Return to Sleeping Death
2FE84E Return whence ye came!
```

Here's another example input:

```
2FE84E Return to Sender
4FFAFC Return of the Obra Dinn
2FE84E Return to the house immediately, young lady!
2FE84E Return to Sleeping Death
2FE84E Return of the Jedi
```

Here's the third example input:

```
2FE84E Return to Sender
4FFAFC Return of the Obra Dinn
2FE84E Return to the house immediately, young lady!
2FE84E Return to Sleeping Death
7217F8 Return of the King
```

Here's the final sample input:

```
F4A52F Eating hearts and livers
F4A52F Eating apples
F4A52F Eating porridge
F4A52F Eating candy houses
F4A52F A Modest Proposal
```

## Outputs:

The "fairest" answer as computed by the specified logic. For example, on the first sample input, the "fairest" answer would be **`Saved by the Seven Dwarfs`**, due to the special hex color `76ADF1` appearing within the input.

In the second sample, there are no special inputs. First, we take "2FE84E Return of the Jedi", which has value #2FE84E. In binary, this is:

```
001011111110100001001110
```

We take the reflection from the mirror, getting:

```
011100100001011111110100
```

We compare it against `2FE84E (001011111110100001001110)` and `4FFAFC (010011111111101011111100)`, which have Hamming distances of 18 and 12 from the reflection, respectively. Since #4FFAFC has the uniquely lowest Hamming distance from the reflection, the "fairest" answer is **`Return of the Obra Dinn`**.

In the third sample input, there are no special inputs. First, we take "7217F8 Return of the King", which has value #7217F8. In binary, this is:

```
011100100001011111111000
```

We take the reflection from the mirror, getting:

```
000111111110100001001110
```

We compare it against `2FE84E (001011111110100001001110)` and `4FFAFC (010011111111101011111100)`, which have Hamming distances of 2 and 8 from the reflection, respectively. All 3 instances of hexadecimal color value #2FE84E have minimum Hamming distance from the reflection, so we take the `(3-1)/2`=`1th` instance (0-indexed) of #2FE84E. Therefore, the "fairest" answer is **`Return to the house immediately, young lady!`**.

In the last sample input, there are no special inputs. First, we take "F4A52F A Modest Proposal", which has value #F4A52F. In binary, this is:

```
1111010011001100101111
```

We take the reflection from the mirror, getting:

```
1111010011001100101111
```

We compare it against `F4A52F (1111010011001100101111)`, which has Hamming distance 0 from the reflection. All instances of hexadecimal color value #F4A52F have minimum Hamming distance from the reflection. There are *FOUR* instances of #F4A52F, because we always exclude the last hexadecimal color instance from evaluation. Therefore, we take the `(4-1)/2=1th` instance (0-indexed) of #F4A52F, and the "fairest" answer is **`Eating apples`**. *If* you don't exclude the last value from consideration, you actually get the `(5-1)/2=2th` instance of #F4A52F (`Eating porridge`), which is wrong.

## Rules:

- No standard loopholes
- Input/output taken via standard input/output methods.
- The output must be exactly equal to the "fairest" answer

## Scoring:

This is code golf, so shortest program wins.

<sub>*Posted~ you can [see it here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194462/mirror-mirror-on-the-wall-whos-the-fairest-of-them-all)*</sub>

Comment: Going to need tag suggestions :)

Comment: Can each entry be taken as a tuple, i.e. `("#FFFFFF","Return the Slab")`? Can the label part also have a hex number in it or are we guaranteed it wont? Rules has the `#` but the examples do not, is either form fine? Can we get a worked example of a list containing multiple matching entries?

Comment: @Veskah You can take tuples as input. You can choose whether to keep `#` in your input hex colors or not, as long as you keep it the same for every single input (no sneaky stuff like putting a `#` before the correct answer every time). I've added more sample inputs/outputs with explanation.

Comment: -1: This has way too many hardcoded input/output mappings. This challenge is more about encoding those than solving a problem.

Answer (score -1):

## Interpret Unneccesary (Not quite)

Unneccesary is a joke language created by Keymaker. The source is unneccesary, and if given, it will error out.

Your task here is similar. If there is input, your program should error out. If the input is empty, your program should do nothing and **terminate**.

Comment: What does it mean to error out?

Comment: @Beefster throw a runtime error... Or?

Comment: What if I'm using a language that does not have terminal errors such as Bash?

Comment: @Beefster Are there any specifications for, something like error quine?

Answer (score -1):

## CMC: Cross-Multiplication Calculator [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

In this task you should create a Cross-Multiplication Calculator.

---

Cross-multiplication is a way of factoring an algebraic expression. This is the expression form that this way can solve:

$$x^2 + ax + b$$

\$a\$ and \$b\$ are constants here, and \$x\$ is a variable.

<sup>Anyway, as far as I can tell, this expression form is only  solvable in this method.</sup>

## Anyway, how do I do Cross-Multiplication? (TODO)

> You first take the number \$b\$ and factor this number into integral factors.

Okay. We are using the expression \$x^2 + 8x + 16\$ as an example.

(Although 16 is not a prime) let us assume that 16 only has 2 possible factors:

- \$-1 \times -16\$ (because \$-x \times -x = x^2\$)
- \$1 \times 16\$ (Obviously this is 16)
- And the above 2 with the factors reversed.

> Now you sum these possible two factors and check this against the number \$a\$.

- Check 1. So \$-1 + (-16) = -17\$. And unfortunately -17 is not 8, we proceed to the next check.
- Check 2. So \$1 + 16 = 17\$. And unfortunately 17 is not 8, we proceed to the next check. There are no checks left.

Did I make a mistake? Of course, I need to change the factors.

- \$-2 \times -8\$ (because \$-x \times -x = x^2\$)
- \$2 \times 8\$ (Obviously this is 16)
- And the above 2 with the factors reversed.

We sum those values, and they are -10 and 10 respectively. So I should change the factors to another value:

- \$-4 \times -4\$ (because \$-x \times -x = x\$)
- \$4 \times 4\$ (Obviously this is 16)
- And the above 2 with the factors reversed.

Finally! \$4+4 = 8\$, and here is the factorization:

$$(x+4)(x+4)$$

<sup>Now you will probably realize why I desperately need a program to automate this.</sup>

## Test cases

You can assume that the input is always valid. You do not have to specify the variables, only the numbers. Therefore the expression

$$x^2 + ax + b$$

is converted into:

$$+a \, +b$$

The expected output is not:

$$(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$$

but:

$$+\alpha \, +\beta$$

```
a, b => α, β
8, 16 => 4, 4
-5, -24 => 3, -8
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Meta

- Is this clear enough?
- I haven't found a duplicate, but anything? (Although unlikely, I found nothing by searching "Cross Multiplication".)
- Tags are code-golf, string and interpreter. Anything else?
- Any further feedback?

Comment: I've edited your post to use MathJax for the mathematical formula/workings. In addition, I've edited out the rather strict input/output format (leading `+` etc.) as it's generally recommended to allow the most natural output format. Feel free to revert these changes if you dislike them. Also, your tags bullet point in the **Meta** section appears to be different to the tags in the title?

Comment: Finally, I'd vote to close this as a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154001/66833) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/find-real-roots-of-a-polynomial?noredirect=1&lq=1) challenge (as it is a subset of both)

Answer (score -1):

## Parse a regex

Grep is a wonderful tool. It can find stuff in files, it can help you spell stuff correctly (`grep 'whatever' /usr/share/dict/words` or wherever that file is), and it can even test if something is a prime number!

However, the first version was implemented back in the golden age, when FORTRAN was respected, Pascal was the language for beginners, and object orientation was just starting out in on its great adventure.

One could argue that modern developers have nowhere near that much talent or skill, what with their flashy "IDEs" and "frameworks". If they would be asked to implement something similar, they would just jump at the nearest library or cloud thingimabob and say "Done!".

At least, that is what some would say.

### Prove them wrong! Golf grep!

Parse a regular expression without calling any built-in functions or operators explicitly meant for this.

### input:

Basically the same as a simple grep: a regular expression as a command line parameter, followed by an optional filename or a dash. If the filename is not present, or it is a dash, read for stdin.

This is the recommended way to do it, but if you can write an adapter (eg: post stuff to a php form for your program via a shell script), then that is OK as well. The adapter does not contribute to your score.

### output

Lines that match the regular expression.

### Notes:

The regex dialect is PCRE (perl compatible). Files use unix line terminators if it is relevant.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7024/42963), but not *quite* a duplicate.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You've likely been downvoted because you "ban built-in functions or operations explicitly meant for this." Consider [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/31625) for a lengthy discussion of why this has fallen out of favour. Beyond this being trivial besides parsing regular expressions, it also doesn't actually describe what a regex is or what it means to be PCRE. Challenges need to be self contained! I think your bet is to make a different matching language yourself and ask us to implement grep but with that language instead of regex.

Answer (score -1):

## Predict the state of a Minecraft inventory after click events

Minecraft does inventory management over the network by sending packets describing the clicks that a player does. If you're caching these events, it can be non-trivial to predict what state the inventory is in after the clicks

### Challenge

Take an inventory of 9 slots, each with an item and a type. Assume all items can stack up to 64 and that if a slot would be "overfilled" that the cursor will continue holding onto the items. Then, take a list of the slot index, button, and mode variables for the clicks to be done (mode and button are defined at https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Click_Window). Output the inventory afterwards.

### Restrictions/Rules

You may input and output the inventory in any reasonable format.
You may take click input in any reasonable format.
You may ignore Mode==2, as the player inventory is not implemented correctly enough for this. 
You may ignore Mode==3 because this is a survival player
You may ignore Mode==5 where Button==8, 9, or 10 for the same reason as Mode 3.
Dropping the item is a delete. Your player won't pick it back up or anything silly like that.
You may assume that input will have valid counts
Don't use standard loopholes

### Examples

Input:

```
[["diamond",64],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

[
 [0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1]
]
```

Output

```
[[],["diamond",64],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Input:

```
[["diamond",64],["dirt", 64],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

[
 [0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 2]
]
```

Output

```
[[],["diamond",64],["dirt",64],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Input:

```
[["diamond",64],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

[
 [0, 0, 0],
 [-999, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 5],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 5],
 [6, 4, 5],
 [7, 4, 5],
 [8, 4, 5],
 [-999, 4, 6],
 [8, 0, 0]
]
```

Output

```
[["diamond",56],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1],["diamond",1]]
```

## Meta

I have no clue what I'm doing writing a question.

Tagged code golf

Critique goals:

- Improve testcases
- Improve description of problem
- Determine if the problem is too complex

Comment: Challenges are meant to be self-contained. While information where the idea/process comes from can be nice, everything needed to solve the challenge should be in the description. This means you should write down what click does what, for all the people who don't remember what Minecraft clicks do by heart.

Answer (score -1):

A very-very old (maybe early 2000s) problem:

> Print out a decimal number \$n\$ such as \$n^2\$ ends with \$n\$ with maximal length your program can compute in `60` seconds

In other words it's needed to find some long enough \$n\$ such as \$10^{\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1}|(n^2-n)\$.
A hint may be that an \$n\$ ending with \$5\$ is more easy to compute than an \$n\$ ending with \$6\$.

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: How can this be [tag:king-of-the-hill]? Do you mean [tag:code-challenge]? And what stops us from hardcoding some extremely large number?

Comment: [tag:king-of-the-hill] needs interaction between submissions. I don't see any here

Comment: @JoKing the problem becomes very simple with modular arithmetic: got [205k digits](https://tio.run/##bVDbasMwDH33VwRCIZd1VVpKR0H7ir2HzHGpSeoYR6Xe12e@pGkL1YN1js5BsqT/6Dyo3Zc20yQvejCUkLwIRoA@f2ozcDGOtSdZzqge@hYJGEdgqXSPwj1T21rhFkKurUcWK3Y7y14kP@YqjixxwUtX9ECeEr6qAAARojRXMzq@m5p/7w8lPVl9aCMVZfyD1gT5i/JrRNMtlTQanc1//eGcNwncFlhBQKkFtMVM4jqbzSLK@wYdRm11d4ZmKuISu8I@NfA8C45Sras8bdo2qM04CnfupZO7xjT9Aw) for free with ~len(n) time for each step https://imgur.com/ExPdwMb , so there's no need for hardcoding and it's not much interesting. )

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript: Free for All

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

This is a *very experimental* idea of mine: given a function which is provided a single function as an argument, try to run that function the most times possible in a browser environment while competing against other bots.

### Bot submissions

Each bot consists of a function. This function takes a scoring function as input. Each bot has a state consisting of three values:

- `score`: Number indicating score, winning criterion
- `locked`: Boolean which, when true, prevents further score increases
- `calls`: Number of times scoring function called in last 100ms (?), will set `locked` to true for the remainder of the round if it exceeds a certain value

The scoring function increments `score` and `calls`, as long as `locked` is not true.

### Restrictions

If any of these restrictions are violated, a bot will have `locked` set to true.

No bot or bot-defined function may:

- Run longer than 5ms
- Attempt to modify the window location (`location.href`, `location.assign`, etc.)
- Attempt to connect to the internet (AJAX, WebSockets, etc.)
- Create web workers
- Affect hardware (sound, microphone, camera, USB, gamepads, etc.)
- Download files
- Leave an impact which cannot be fixed by reloading the page

### Notes

This is almost certainly a very bad idea on an assortment of levels. If you have any suggestions of restrictions or ways to make the challenge more interesting, be sure to comment.

I'm considering some sort of system to determine which bot runs first that adds to the strategy, and interesting attack angles for other bots.

To prevent this from becoming a "read the last answer and exactly cancel out its strategy" type thing, I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Given a digit as an English word, output its numerical value.

For example, given the input `one`, you should output `1` (optionally with a trailing newline).

Your program should cover all the following cases:

```
zero  => 0
one   => 1
two   => 2
three => 3
four  => 4
five  => 5
six   => 6
seven => 7
eight => 8
nine  => 9
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate I can't find, and this is definitely a large subset of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/convert-a-string-of-digits-from-words-to-an-integer.

Answer (score -1):

## Introduction

This challenge was inspired by the [24 Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game).

In the 24 Game, you are given 4 numbers and are asked to make 24 using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and parentheses. So...

What is the biggest number you can make given 4 numbers using the above operations?

## Challenge

For four given inputs `a, b, c, d`, output the biggest number you can get using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and parentheses.

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
  Input  -->  Output  -->   Explanation
 1,3,2,4 -->    36    --> (1 + 2) × 3 × 4
 5,5,5,5 -->   625    -->  5 × 5 × 5 × 5
 9,2,3,1 -->    81    --> (1 + 2) × 3 × 9
```

---

Please give feedback on this challenge and correct me if my outputs are wrong. Should I change it to the smallest number?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131567/operator-precedence-how-wrong-can-i-be).

Comment: Also the subtraction and division are surely obsolete for the challenge?

Comment: Will positive number divide zero yield Infinity as what IEEE 754 does?

Comment: Shouldn't `(1+2)x3x4` greater than `1+2x3x4`?

Comment: @FlipTack Probably but maybe not in some circumstances.

Comment: @tsh No, infinity will not count as the solution. Thank you, that is true that `(1+2)x3x4` is greater.

Comment: Does order matter? From the input it seems the order matters, i.e. we are not supposed to change the order of the input. So, for 1,3,2,4, the answer is 32, rather than 36.

Comment: @Element118 No, order does not matter, those were just the random numbers that came from my head.

Answer (score -1):

## How many ACus do I have?

Posted to [main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197816/56555)

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as a dupe, but what it seems to be is `n=floor(days_between(input, date(1,1,2020)) / 7); return n*(n-1)/2`, which doesn't seem terribly interesting to golf. (Also just fyi, the `01` you used in your dates in your script is actually an octal literal i.e. `010` is 8)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have corrected the script. Not sure how the extra 0's managed to slip in! I'll leave the challenge here for a couple more days to see if there are any more comments.

Comment: @ElPedro You need to wait longer. At least a month or two, but a few months is really good.

Comment: I'm sorry and no personal offence intended but I find it a bit strange that a member of 3 months is telling a member of over 4 years with lot's of experience and over 5000 rep how to use the sandbox and the main site. Maybe I am simply getting too old for this community.

Comment: And besides which, none of that alters my opinion that downvotes without the downvoter giving a reason are not any help to anyone. If you think differently then please feel free to give me a good reason. I am happy to listen and learn.

Answer (score -1):

## Make a Decompiler Bomb

Similar to the [Make a Compiler Bomb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69189/build-a-compiler-bomb) challenge, but backwards.

The goal is to create the a 1KiB (1024 bytes) or smaller bytecode file that creates the largest output when decompiled.

## Constraints

- A binary is either an x86 binary (in the form of an ELF file, PE file (.dll/.exe), or Mach-O binary) or a virtual bytecode file (e.g. Python .pyc, Java .class, .NET CLR, etc.)
- The decompiler can be any public (preferably free) decompiler of your choice. (e.g Snowman/Hex-Rays for x86 binarys, CFR/Fernflower/etc. for java, dotPeek for .NET, uncompyle6 for Python, etc.)
- A decompiler is any tool that takes a binary and attempts to reconstruct human readable source code from it.
- The largest output byte count wins, with the smallest input size as a tie-breaker
- The binary must be executable, and print "Hello World!"
- The decompiled code must be syntactically correct

Comment: I think you probably want to specify what a "decompiler" is, since really any file is "binary" and anything that takes that and produces some valid code probably arguable counts as a decompiler. Further, I think you might be better served by limiting the binary size, like the original challenge, as if someone finds a way that adding \$n\$ bytes adds more than \$n^{2}\$ bytes to the output they would achieve an arbitrarily large score.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I put in a basic explanation and made the scoring based on largest output rather than a formula. Explaining a decompiler is tricky though, I'll think about that more and maybe edit for it later.

Comment: I think the scoring change you made is good, only that `kb` is a tad ambiguous between being 1000 or 1024, and that it seems a tad large (but neither of those is critical and the second is just my opinion). Thinking about what to do with the problem of defining a decompiler, I realised it was probably a good idea to require that the resulting decompiled code does something. Maybe requiring that the decompiled code is a hello world variant or something will limit some problems like "this program converts to Unary source code".

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Made it so the decompiled code must have correct syntax, and made the size smaller, was going to post my java example but I just realized I have to make it fit in the new restrictions so...

Answer (score -1):

## I delete the input, you delete the source code

[file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

This is a new twist on the long running series on CGCC.

Your task, if you accept it, is to write a program/function that outputs/returns the contents of an input file. The tricky part is that if I delete the input file, your program must delete itself.

### Rules

- The source code file and the input file should be in the same directory.
- The input file and source file can be named anything at all. I.e. The file names are your choice.
- The contents of the input file will be restricted to printable ASCII.
- The input file and the source file **must** be deletable.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest (original) code in each language wins!
- Default Loopholes apply.

### Example

If your program is `jspwjxnlow8229` and the input file exists, the program must print the contents of the file. If the file doesn't exist, the program must delete itself.

### Feedback

In regards to file manipulation, have I specified the rules enough?

Comment: What about languages in which programs don't live in files but rather in binary blobs? Is it enough for the program to delete itself from the binary blob?

Comment: Can the program and/or source file also be named anything at all?

Comment: @Adam, forgive me for not knowing, but what's a binary blob?

Comment: It doesn't matter what a binary blob is. I just wanted you to be aware than not all languages use the same model.

Comment: @Adam sure. I'll add a part about that to the challenge

Comment: Parts of this feel a bit unclear. Can the submissions know the file names in advance? (If not then the name feels a bit odd, isn't it really write a cat program that deletes itself if the input name doesn't correspond to an existing file? They aren't really tied together in that case) Similarly, why mention the recycling bin? It isn't present on many systems, and behaves differently on those that do have one (most programmatic deletions will require more work to send the file to the temporary "are you sure" location).

Answer (score -1):

## How healthy are my children?

As anyone who has twins will know, it can be hard to keep track of which child fed / was changed, and when.

That's why I've devised a system using OneNote on my phone. It's quick and easy to use.

Each entry (line) uses the following structure (note: I'm not a regex expert and the expression is more permissive than I want - see words for detail):

> (ddMMyyyy )?HHmm ((1|2|B) (||){1,3}){1,3}

Or, in words:

1. For the first entry on or after midnight each day only, each line starts with the date.
2. The next component is always the time, hour and minute in 24 hour clock format
3. Next is a child identifier character - `1` or `2`; or `B` if what follows applies to both children. All subsequent emoticons apply to the identified child, until a new child identifier is found or a newline. There is guaranteed to be at least one child identifier in a record.
4. Next comes any or all of the three emoticons (maximum one of each) representing a wet nappy (), a dirty nappy () or a feed ()
5. Repeat from step 3. until done. BUT - each emoticon will only appear once per child - so if it appears in `B` then it won't appear in either `1` or `2`; and if it appears in either `1` or `2` it won't appear in `B`. It won't appear in both `1` and `2` (because then it would be in `B` instead). The regex doesn't show this subtlety.

Some other notes:

- Breast-Feeding (feed) emoticon  is codepoint U+1F931
- Droplet (wet) emoticon  is codepoint U+1F4A7
- Pile of Poo (dirty) emoticon  is codepoint U+1F4A9
- All items in the string are space-separated
- I would actually use the initials of my children's names, rather than `1` and `2` - but for the challenge I went with the numbers instead.

### Example

02022020 0005 1  B  
0230 2  
0250 1   
0330 2 
0400 1 
0700 B  
0900 2 
1000 2  
1020 1  
1220 1 
1420 B  1  2 
1440 1 
1600 2  
1700 1 
1745 B 
2100 B   1 
2350 2  B  1 
03022020 0015 1  B 
0500 1  
0830 1  
0900 2  
1115 B  1 
1215 B 
1330 B 
1400 2

## The Challenge

Given the raw data, input as a single string or array of entries, containing data such as the above example, output a summary of:

- number of feeds, wet and dirty nappies, per baby, over the past 24 hours

"The past 24 hours" can be either based on system time, or the current time can be passed as an extra input.

The output format is up to you, as long as it:

a) is consistent across all runs of the program
b) shows the information required

some example outputs for the above inputs, with a current time of 14:30 on 3rd of February 2020 (hand-calculated, sorry if they're not right!):

`Baby 1 had 6 wet nappies, 2 dirty nappies, and fed 8 times
Baby 2 had 6 wet nappies, 3 dirty nappies and fed 6 times`

`{{6,6},{2,3},{8,6}}`

`{6,2,8},{6,3,6}`

etc.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest bytes wins. Usual exclusions apply.

Comment: If a language can't deal with unicode input, should I allow the whole codepoint string substituted in its place?

Comment: Should I be more explicit with the output format?

Comment: Can someone help me make the regex more tight?

Answer (score -1):

I want to ask a combined popularity / objectively scored question. Something like:

> Take a string as input. Match the string to a famous painting such as "Mona Lisa" and render a cartoon version of it. 1 point per painting, 1 point per upvote. Voting closes on XX/YY/ZZZZ.

I want to reward people for including more possibilities (there will be a fixed upper limit, unlike with paintings). I also want to reward people for the quality of their renderings. The cartoon paintings should be recognisable as versions of the real paintings.

Is this a good scoring system? If not, what would be better?

Comment: This is somewhat vague. Can you be more precise?

Answer (score -1):

## Implement PSL(2,3)

*Since challenge to implement Galois field already have been many, I'm writing a challenge involving a group of Lie type!*

### Objective

Implement the multiplication and inversion in \$\text{PSL}(2,3)\$.

### The ring \$\mathbb{Z}_3\$

The ring \$\mathbb{Z}_3\$ is the set \$\{0,1,2\}\$ with **addition**, **negation**, **subtraction**, and **multiplication** defined as **modular arithmetic**:

- Addition is the usual addition with the result moduloed by 3;
- Negation, subtraction, and multiplication are also analogously defined.

**Reciprocal** and **division** is also well-defined, but that's just another detail.

### The group \$\text{SL}(2,3)\$

The multiplicative group \$\text{SL}(2,3)\$ is the set of 2-by-2 matrices whose entries are members of \$\mathbb{Z}_3\$ and the determinant is \$1\$. Note that the determinant is calculated using modular arithmetic. **Matrix multiplication** and **matrix inversion** is defined as:

- Matrix multiplication is the usual matrix multiplication, where addition and multiplication of the entries are modular;
- Matrix inversion of \$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\$ is \$\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}\$. This exploits that the determinant is \$1\$.

As a consequence, the elements of \$\text{SL}(2,3)\$ are:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

### The factor group \$\text{PSL}(2,3)\$

\$\text{PSL}(2,3)\$ is defined as **cosets** of \$\text{SL}(2,3)\$ by \$\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\}\$. That is, elementwise multiplications of \$\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\}\$.
They are:
$$
\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}\},
\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\},
$$

You pick an element of each coset as representives, and *don't care* about the rest.

Multiplication/inversion of such representives is defined as multiplication/inversion in \$\text{SL}(2,3)\$, then taking the representive of the coset the multiplication/inversion is in. For example, \$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\$, if \$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}\$ and \$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\$ are representives.

### Examples

Picking the left elements as representives of the cosets above:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$
To be more specific about the method of evaluation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}^{-1} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} ≡ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$
The steps of this algorithm is:

1. Do usual matrix multiplication/inversion;
2. Modulo the entries by 3;
3. Take the representive of the coset.

Though you can make any possible algorithm.

### Rules

- Input type and format doesn't matter, but it must be a container of integers. In C, `int[2][2]` and `int[4]` are valid examples. This restriction prevents abusing the fact that \$\text{PSL}(2,3) \cong A_4\$.
- Output type and format doesn't matter either, but it must be the same as the input type and format.
- Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation.
- Multiplication and inversion may be in separate codes. In this case, the score is the sum of their lengths in bytes.
- Since this is a code-golf, the code with least score wins.

Comment: This challenge appears to heavily rely on [tag:restricted-source] and thus to me does not seem too viable.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Do you think I should lift the restriction on input type? Otherwise, "You pick an element of each coset as representives, and *don't care* about the rest" and "Invalid inputs fall in *don't care* situation" should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

### Numbers by index

**Challenge**

Print the numbers:

```
0
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

In that order.

**I/O**

Takes no input. The numbers can have any delimiters desired (or none). Example outputs:

```
0122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999

[0,1,22,333,4444,55555,666666,7777777,88888888,999999999]

etc....
```

**Code Example**

This is an un-golfed example that may perhaps act as algorithm guide (or maybe not):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 553 bytes

```
0 * 0 r K
K * _ r 1
1 * 1 r L
L * _ r 2
2 * 2 r a
a * 2 r M
M * _ r 3
3 * 3 r b
b * 3 r c
c * 3 r N
N * _ r 4
4 * 4 r d
d * 4 r e
e * 4 r f
f * 4 r O
O * _ r 5
5 * 5 r g
g * 5 r h
h * 5 r i 
i * 5 r j
j * 5 r P
P * _ r 6
6 * 6 r k
k * 6 r l
l * 6 r m
m * 6 r n
n * 6 r o
o * 6 r Q
Q * _ r 7
7 * 7 r p
p * 7 r q
q * 7 r r
r * 7 r s
s * 7 r t
t * 7 r u
u * 7 r R
R * _ r 8
8 * 8 r v
v * 8 r w
w * 8 r x
x * 8 r y
y * 8 r z
z * 8 r A
A * 8 r B
B * 8 r S
S * _ r 9
9 * 9 r C
C * 9 r D
D * 9 r E
E * 9 r F
F * 9 r G
G * 9 r H
H * 9 r I
I * 9 r J
J * 9 r halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?23aea82be925a0c78e78ea9e7912363d)

This prints out the numbers with a space delimiter:

```
0 1 22 333 4444 55555 666666 7777777 88888888 999999999
```

**Challenge Type**

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes (by language) wins.

***Edit:*** [Link to the related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/numbers-by-position). Curiously, there is one answer on there where if it was by index, and the zero was included, [it would be shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/numbers-by-position/201379#201379).

Comment: Nice challenge! Are preceding & trailing whitespace (during string output) permitted?

Comment: I think it should also be [tag:kolgomorov-complexity].

Comment: I don't like how the zero breaks the pattern of having the digit N appear N times -- it seems like an [exceptional edge case](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17611/20260). I think it would be better for 0 not to appear, so the numbers would just start from 1.

Comment: @xnor, I knew you wouldn't like it (and probably a few other won't as well) That's on purpose. It just seems a little *too easy* otherwise.

Comment: @a'_', Yes. @ PkmnQ, Noted.

Comment: I don't really see how adding a fixed zero to the beginning makes the challenge harder in almost any language. In some, the [empty string will actually convert to zero](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P7dYKyUhJeT/fwA), which makes it more natural but still fairly trivial. I feel like you probably either want to go with omitting the zero, or finding a different way to make the challenge more complicated.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, How can you have a challenge about indexes and not have zero? That just seems wrong.

Comment: Most people start counting from one - only people who use computers a lot default to starting at zero. And separately, I think finding another way to incorporate it is better than leaving it out (I just also think both are better than having an unexplained outlier).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, But it's not really unexplained is it? It's the index of the first number.

Comment: As per what xnor said, it doesn't match the pattern of the others. That behaviour is not explained. Comments aren't really for a discussion like this; if you disagree that is fine. I've just given feedback on how I think you could improve the challenge.

Comment: I do want to make sure that everyone knows that I am VERY grateful for the feedback! I also appreciate having a Sandbox where we can have this discussion here instead of on the main site.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, It's not that I disagree. I kind of agree. I like that leading zero in there to represent the index location of the initial value. I considered this when I thought of the question, before posting it here. It breaks up a trivial loop sequence answer a bit, or maybe even inspires a clever solution that nobody considered. I'd like to keep it *because* it stands out like that, not *despite* that.

Comment: I posted an example implementation above. The zero wasn't a big deal.

Comment: My guess is that you're excited about the arithmetic expression `10**n/9*n` or similar. But I don't think that's much more interesting than the obvious loops that removing the zero would allow unmodified.

Comment: @xnor, Don't get me wrong. I love me some maths every now and then. I even got a bachelor's in it a long long time ago. But I think it might be a bit of a stretch to say I get excited about arithmetic expressions....

Comment: @ouflak I contrast, I am [very excited about arithmetic expressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170398/20260) :)

Comment: [A variant of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/numbers-by-position) is on the main site.

Answer (score -1):

### Very rough outline of a challenge that rewards short programs that take a long time.

Probably a no input and output can be anything except an error challenge.

Is there a nice way to exclude things like `sleep()`, `wait()` etc?

Would be required for 1 person to run all the programs for the timing to be fair.

Thinking that answers would include loops, recursion, testing of complex criteria.

Comment: I think you would have to post your challenge as a popularity contest ... a slippery slope indeed.

Answer (score -1):

## A malbolge interpreter

The challenge today is to write a Malbolge interpreter.

### Specification

```
Malbolge
'98, Ben Olmstead

I hereby relenquish any and all copyright on this language,
documentation, and interpreter; Malbolge is officially public domain.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                Malbolge
                           '98, Ben Olmstead

Introduction
^^^^^^^^^^^^

It was noticed that, in the field of esoteric programming languages,
there was a particular and surprising void: no programming language
known to the author was specifically designed to be difficult to program
in.

Certainly, there were languages which were difficult to write in, and
far more were difficult to read (see: Befunge, False, TWDL, RUBE...).
But even INTERCAL and BrainF***, the two kings of mental torment, were
designed with other goals: INTERCAL to have nothing in common with any
major programming language, and BrainF*** to be a very tiny, yet still
Turing-complete, language.

INTERCAL's constructs are certainly tortuous, but they are all too
flexible; you can, for instance, quite easily assign any number to a
variable with a single statement.

BrainF*** is lacking the flexibility which is INTERCAL's major weakness,
but it fails in that its constructs are far, far too intuitive.
Certainly, there are only 8 instructions, none of which take any
arguments--but it is quite easy to determine how to use those
instructions.  Subtract 8 from the current number?  With a simple
'--------' you are done!  This kind of simple answer was unacceptable to
the author.

Hence the author created Malbolge.  It borrows from machine, BrainF***,
and tri-INTERCAL, but put together in a unique way.  It was designed to
be difficult to use, and so it is.  It is designed to be
incomprehensible, and so it is.

So far, no Malbolge programs have been written.  Thus, we cannot give an
example.

"Malbolge" is the name of Dante's Eighth Circle of Hell, in which
practitioners of deception (seducers, flatterers, simonists, thieves,
hypocrites, and so on) spend eternity.


Environment
^^^^^^^^^^^

In many languages, the environment is easy to understand.  In Malbolge,
it is best to understand the runtime environment before you ever see a
command.

The environment is, roughly, that of a primitive trinary CPU.  Both code
and data share the same space (the machine's memory segment), and there
are three registers.  Machine words are ten trits (trinary digits) wide,
giving a maximum possible value of 59048 (all numbers are unsigned).
Memory space is exactly 59049 words long.

The three registers are A, C, and D.  A is the accumulator, used for
data manipulation.  A is implicitly set to the value written by all
write operations on memory.  (Standard I/O, a distinctly non-chip-level
feature, is done directly with the A register.)

C is the code pointer.  It is automatically incremented after each
instruction, and points the instruction being executed.

D is the data pointer.  It, too, is automatically incremented after each
instruction, but the location it points to is used for the data
manipulation commands.

All registers begin with the value 0.

When the interpreter loads the program, it ignores all whitespace.  If
it encounters anything that is not one of an instruction and is not
whitespace, it will give an error, otherwise it loads the file, one non-
whitespace character per cell, into memory.  Cells which are not
initialized are set by performing op on the previous two cells
repetitively.


Commands
^^^^^^^^

When the interpreter tries to execute a program, it first checks to
see if the current instruction is a graphical ASCII character (33
through 126).  If it is, it subtracts 33 from it, adds C to it, mods it
by 94, then uses the result as an index into the following table of 94
characters:

            +b(29e*j1VMEKLyC})8&m#~W>qxdRp0wkrUo[D7,XTcA"lI
            .v%{gJh4G\-=O@5`_3i<?Z';FNQuY]szf$!BS/|t:Pn6^Ha

It then checks it against the characters listed below, and performs an
appropriate action.

If the result is not one of the characters listed below, it is treated
as a nop.  If the original character is not graphic ASCII, the program
is immediately ended.

When the interpreter parses the input file, it checks each non-
whitespace character with the process above.  If any result is not one
of the eight characters below, the file will be rejected.

After the instruction is executed, 33 is subtracted from the instruction
at C, and the result is used as an index in the table below.  The new
character is then placed at C, and then C is incremented.

            5z]&gqtyfr$(we4{WP)H-Zn,[%\3dL+Q;>U!pJS72FhOA1C
            B6v^=I_0/8|jsb9m<.TVac`uY*MK'X~xDl}REokN:#?G"i@

j
  sets the data pointer to the value in the cell pointed to by the
  current data pointer.

i
  sets the code pointer to the value in the cell pointed to be the
  current data pointer.

*
  rotates the trinary value of the cell pointed to by D to the right 1.
  The least significant trit becomes the most significant trit, and all
  others move one position to the left.

p
  performs a tritwise "op" on the value pointed to by D with the
  contents of A.  The op (don't look for pattern, it's not there) is:

            | A trit:
    ________|_0__1__2_
          0 | 1  0  0
      *D  1 | 1  0  2
     trit 2 | 2  2  1



Di-trits:
    00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22

00  04 03 03 01 00 00 01 00 00
01  04 03 05 01 00 02 01 00 02
02  05 05 04 02 02 01 02 02 01
10  04 03 03 01 00 00 07 06 06
11  04 03 05 01 00 02 07 06 08
12  05 05 04 02 02 01 08 08 07
20  07 06 06 07 06 06 04 03 03
21  07 06 08 07 06 08 04 03 05
22  08 08 07 08 08 07 05 05 04

<
  reads an ASCII value from the stdin and converts it to Trinary, then
  stores it in A.  10 (line feed) is considered 'newline', and
  2222222222t (59048 dec.) is EOF.

/
  converts the value in A to ASCII and writes it to stdout.  Writing
  10 is a newline.

v
  indicates a full stop for the machine.

o
  does nothing, except increment C and D, as all other instructions do.


Turing-Completeness
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Though I have not proven it, I _think_ Malbolge to be Turing-complete.
To be Turing-complete, there must be some data construct which can be
used to do any mathematical calculation.  I believe that using *p in
various clever ways on the tritwords can fulfill this requirement.

Turing-completeness also requires three code constructs: sequential
execution (which Malbolge obviously has), repetition (provided by the
i and, indirectly, j instructions), and conditional-execution (provided,
I believe, by self-modifying code and altering i destinations).

I do have my doubts, particularly about data constructs, but I *think*
this works...


Appendix: Trinary Conversion Table
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Trinary to ASCII to decimal to hex table, provided, strangely enough,
for the convenience of Malbolge programmers.

00000 NUL 000 00    01012   032 20    02101 @ 064 40    10120 ` 096 60
00001 SOH 001 01    01020 ! 033 21    02102 A 065 41    10121 a 097 61
00002 STX 002 02    01021 " 034 22    02110 B 066 42    10122 b 098 62
00010 ETX 003 03    01022 # 035 23    02111 C 067 43    10200 c 099 63
00011 EOT 004 04    01100 $ 036 24    02112 D 068 44    10201 d 100 64
00012 ENQ 005 05    01101 % 037 25    02120 E 069 45    10202 e 101 65
00020 ACK 006 06    01102 & 038 26    02121 F 070 46    10210 f 102 66
00021 BEL 007 07    01110 ' 039 27    02122 G 071 47    10211 g 103 67
00022 BS  008 08    01111 ( 040 28    02200 H 072 48    10212 h 104 68
00100 HT  009 09    01112 ) 041 29    02201 I 073 49    10220 i 105 69
00101 LF  010 0a    01120 * 042 2a    02202 J 074 4a    10221 j 106 6a
00102 VT  011 0b    01121 + 043 2b    02210 K 075 4b    10222 k 107 6b
00110 FF  012 0c    01122 , 044 2c    02211 L 076 4c    11000 l 108 6c
00111 CR  013 0d    01200 - 045 2d    02212 M 077 4d    11001 m 109 6d
00112 SO  014 0e    01201 . 046 2e    02220 N 078 4e    11002 n 110 6e
00120 SI  015 0f    01202 / 047 2f    02221 O 079 4f    11010 o 111 6f
00121 DLE 016 10    01210 0 048 30    02222 P 080 50    11011 p 112 70
00122 DC1 017 11    01211 1 049 31    10000 Q 081 51    11012 q 113 71
00200 DC2 018 12    01212 2 050 32    10001 R 082 52    11020 r 114 72
00201 DC3 019 13    01220 3 051 33    10002 S 083 53    11021 s 115 73
00202 DC4 020 14    01221 4 052 34    10010 T 084 54    11022 t 116 74
00210 NAK 021 15    01222 5 053 35    10011 U 085 55    11100 u 117 75
00211 SYN 022 16    02000 6 054 36    10012 V 086 56    11101 v 118 76
00212 ETB 023 17    02001 7 055 37    10020 W 087 57    11102 w 119 77
00220 CAN 024 18    02002 8 056 38    10021 X 088 58    11110 x 120 78
00221 EM  025 19    02010 9 057 39    10022 Y 089 59    11111 y 121 79
00222 SUB 026 1a    02011 : 058 3a    10100 Z 090 5a    11112 z 122 7a
01000 ESC 027 1b    02012 ; 059 3b    10101 [ 091 5b    11120 { 123 7b
01001 FS  028 1c    02020 < 060 3c    10102 \ 092 5c    11121 | 124 7c
01002 GS  029 1d    02021 = 061 3d    10110 ] 093 5d    11122 } 125 7d
01010 RS  030 1e    02022 > 062 3e    10111 ^ 094 5e    11200 ~ 126 7e
01011 US  031 1f    02100 ? 063 3f    10112 _ 095 5f

11202 128 80    12221 160 a0    21010 192 c0    22022 224 e0
11210 129 81    12222 161 a1    21011 193 c1    22100 225 e1
11211 130 82    20000 162 a2    21012 194 c2    22101 226 e2
11212 131 83    20001 163 a3    21020 195 c3    22102 227 e3
11220 132 84    20002 164 a4    21021 196 c4    22110 228 e4
11221 133 85    20010 165 a5    21022 197 c5    22111 229 e5
11222 134 86    20011 166 a6    21100 198 c6    22112 230 e6
12000 135 87    20012 167 a7    21101 199 c7    22120 231 e7
12001 136 88    20020 168 a8    21102 200 c8    22121 232 e8
12002 137 89    20021 169 a9    21110 201 c9    22122 233 e9
12010 138 8a    20022 170 aa    21111 202 ca    22200 234 ea
12011 139 8b    20100 171 ab    21112 203 cb    22201 235 eb
12012 140 8c    20101 172 ac    21120 204 cc    22202 236 ec
12020 141 8d    20102 173 ad    21121 205 cd    22210 237 ed
12021 142 8e    20110 174 ae    21122 206 ce    22211 238 ee
12022 143 8f    20111 175 af    21200 207 cf    22212 239 ef
12100 144 90    20112 176 b0    21201 208 d0    22220 240 f0
12101 145 91    20120 177 b1    21202 209 d1    22221 241 f1
12102 146 92    20121 178 b2    21210 210 d2    22222 242 f2
12110 147 93    20122 179 b3    21211 211 d3
12111 148 94    20200 180 b4    21212 212 d4
12112 149 95    20201 181 b5    21220 213 d5
12120 150 96    20202 182 b6    21221 214 d6
12121 151 97    20210 183 b7    21222 215 d7
12122 152 98    20211 184 b8    22000 216 d8
12200 153 99    20212 185 b9    22001 217 d9
12201 154 9a    20220 186 ba    22002 218 da
12202 155 9b    20221 187 bb    22010 219 db
12210 156 9c    20222 188 bc    22011 220 dc
12211 157 9d    21000 189 bd    22012 221 dd
12212 158 9e    21001 190 be    22020 222 de
12220 159 9f    21002 191 bf    22021 223 df
```

### Notes

Note that the original specification has one quirk: after encountering an illegal instruction, the interpreter hangs. You may choose which behaviour do you want to implement (hang or exit).

### I/O rules

The program or function *has* to take input in any reasonable way (for the program), and somehow supply the input and output features to the malbolge program (either by return value / parameter, tty or a file).

### Sandbox stuff

note: I'm a bit unsure about the scoring criterion: would popularity-contest be good? I'm mostly looking for creative answers

Comment: add [tag:interpreter] ?

Comment: I think popularity-contest would be adding `Do X creatively` to an already relatively non-interesting challenge [unless if you somehow managed to create a Malbolge self-interpreter and that is the trick you're planning to use to win your own competition with it :) ]

Comment: hmm right; I'm not planning on submitting a malbolge interpreter on malbolge :P, I'd like to see what people can think of.
Also I've been thinking about fastest-code contest that would possibly allow me to switch my tolling a bit :P

Comment: I'd probably participate if this was [fastest-code], but I doubt there are enough interesting optimizations here.

Comment: there is a lot of room for optimization, you just need to investigate the challenge a little bit further

Answer (score -1):

## What day is it today? [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

Given a date `y4y3y2y1-m2m1-d2d1`, output the day in the week `w`. 0 as Sunday, 1 as Monday, and so on. You can assume the date is valid, and we use the current [date rule](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/) and [leap rule](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html).

Each submission should be written in this specific programming language:

- A program consists of a mapping from string of digits to digits, and a sequence of instructions.
- Each instruction has the format: `var=[var|dgt],[var|dgt],...,[var|dgt]`, which assigns the value of looking up the string constructed by concatenating the values of the right hand side elements (`[var|dgt],[var|dgt],...,[var|dgt]`) together in the table and put it into the `var` on the left.

A program is valid if:

- None of the lookup step fails for all valid input date.
- Given any valid date in the format mentioned above (initially assigned to the 8 variables `y4 y3 y2 y1 m2 m1 d2 d1`), after the program is run, the correct result is assigned to the variable `w`.

You can create as many variables as you like(though bounded by amount of instructions), each variable only containing a digit.

Solution win if there's no strictly better solution, aka. no solution that take less or same amount of items in mapping table, less or same amount of instrucions, and at least one of amounts of items and instructions is less.

For example, this is a solution that wins:

> ## 3652425 items 1 instruction

```
003000101 -> 6
003000102 -> 0
003000103 -> 1
...
993991231 -> 5
-------------
w=y4,y3,3,y2,y1,m2,m1,d2,d1
```

Here, the `3` on 3rd position can be used without any extra cost. This can be used to create multiple mappings, and sometimes save elements when there are more mapping instructions.

A checker is provided [here](https://tio.run/##pVNdb5swFH1OfoVXVbpGuCgY8oVHX1Zt2h7Whz5mVSDgJKTEjsBpiii/PbOBbNW09WUWwrJ1fM4959q7@DkukyI7qBshU36@OpYclarIEnXFhuujSFQmBUq2PHnCKl7lnKBMaICF6uHgOS7Q3dcvDyhE9SiAERA3ABcIDYAC8QLwgPgB@EDGAYyBTAKYAJkGMAUyC2AGZB7AHMhyeSikkstlII553rDhoNXQtO3slIc8U9EPETn7@IBVeFsb5Zis2EL/HkPVI8KIFVwdC4EijOVqt4DrOm5AA0zli@t61QNJx5SEt1EPSzQsspydzERkR82jlYnWmoVeX9FRpHydCZ46L1Fjsc54W9onXePnPiUMrQwQBJrUTIYA@sA6ahaZ42tZIGw40vBmQt3JlLpzOjKDofRjSMeeP6LU9f3Lnh3OJt2izb3Vr3xSeaSipHLJnpK9S1JKUpeoUPATuosVx6kRGyzeIntohzXJKfnt4f47bpGGVpdu2vkv9t@tMuZMqwaqqFDdx3G5I5qFdPkxlK1NL5zTB6224eourrBlIbUt5AmNWIOSWCVbzLWzbk@xZjjQXyJFKXPu5HKD8P1qxxPlPPGq7DQsJ@dio7aXeLuVttEM9Di3VsK6Ye9EpS/4/zTivVzftOBXwjoVfcSuPNuzK2pXrr2n9t61U2r/eeQSExu2Lw9hqW/TKewE/@IELHY@/wQ).

Comment: I completely don't understand the entire `You can have a mapping table and some instructions, each instruction write var=[var|dgt],[var|dgt],...,[var|dgt], meaning search the element [var|dgt],[var|dgt],...,[var|dgt]from table and put i into the var on the left. Failure on searching is not allowed. You can create as many variables as you like(though bounded by amount of instructions), each variable only containing a digit.` part.

Comment: I'm very confused about this. Are you sure you're not [making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/43319)?

Comment: @Adám I'm requiring using only this language

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate That mainly mean the only operation is lookup, there's nothing like plus, multiply or whatever

Comment: @l4m2 I still do not understand a word. The whole proposal definitely requires a serious rewrite.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate If it hadn't needed some more time it isn't here

Comment: "Solution win if there's no strictly better solution" is not a valid winning criterion because it allows multiple winners.

Comment: @Bubbler Multiple winners is common

Comment: @l4m2 Do you mean something like ties in code golf? IMO, code golf ties are fine because they can be seen as equally good, while your criterion is not because it allows potentially multiple answers that can't be compared to each other at all.

Comment: @Bubbler I mean like multiple languages each only comparing to self

Comment: @l4m2 [The winning criterion is the guide to optimize one's solution in one direction](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8135/78410). "Shortest solution in each language wins" does not harm this spirit. Yours don't give which one to optimize for: mapping table size or instruction size?

Comment: @Bubbler Your link claims you wrong

Comment: @l4m2 OK, let me say it in a different way. You already showed a "winning" solution with minimal instructions. Then there will be a "winning" solution with minimal table, and then there can be thousands of "winning" solutions in between. Given any "winning" solution, one can tweak a little to get another "winning" solution. Do you really think it is fun?

Comment: @Bubbler Yea an exact bound of table size for each instruction count, if exist, makes its sense

Comment: @Bubbler You don't like to see lots of winners because you think "win" is a big issue?

Comment: [Meta post about this sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/is-a-solution-wins-if-theres-no-strictly-better-solution-in-multiple-measures).

Answer (score -1):

Write two programs (likely functions since IO for float convert to/from stream, losing info as mentioned later), one given \$n\geq 2\$ real points on a 2D plane, returning \$2n-3\$ real numbers; another given the \$2n-3\$ real numbers, return the same shape and size given to first program. Order of points matters. Returning a mirrored shape is fine.

You must use an in-language float and assume it is infinitely precise, but converting to types like string or trying to handle the bits in RAM truncate the precision. There's no requirements on how you map, so you can even just pack some real numbers into one if your language happens to have way to do that.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Should the last sentence be "you can't"?

Comment: Is the rotation (orientation) important? (if it doesn't, I assume that it's possible to use 2n-4 real numbers?)

Comment: @user202729 Rotation not important, size important. You are allowed if able, but as I know no language do that

Comment: But it's not an observable behavior (although there's no built-in for it, it's possible to simply interleave the digits, while it's not possible to do it in finite time for irrational floating point numbers -- alternatively you can assume that only coordinates with finite binary representation are valid input). You can require that the mapping is (almost everywhere) continuous, however.

Comment: Can I use multiple floating point types in a language (e.g. float and double in C)?

Comment: @Bubbler What may it be used to?

Comment: Combine two floats into a double at the bit level.

Comment: @Bubbler It'll likely result in nan

Comment: No, simple concatenation of two floats (not a NaN or Infinity) is guaranteed to give a value that is neither NaN nor Infinity. cf. [Single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), [Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @Bubbler Anyway now doing such lose precision

Comment: OK, that would work.

Comment: (you didn't answer my last question.)

Comment: @user202729 How 2n-4?

Comment: No, the latter question about unobservable behavior.

Comment: @user202729 What does the `it` refer?

Comment: The user must not manually implement the "pack two real numbers into one" unless it's a built-in in the language.

Comment: @user202729 As you mentioned you can't

Comment: I don't see why you should restrict bitwise operation.. Could you please explain why? As an alternative you can require that the results are within an epsilon of the correct answer (where epsilon is the smallest positive representable value).

Comment: I mean, the restriction violates [Don't allow / ask for different things in languages with different capabilities](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/).

Answer (score -1):

## Natural Language Identification Using Only Regular Expressions

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sandbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandbox) [winning-criteria](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winning-criteria) [discussion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

For example:

```js
const regex = /English(?=\w+ Hello World)|Spanish(?= Hola Mundo)/;

console.log('EnglishSpanish Hello World'.match(regex)); // English
console.log('EnglishSpanish Hola Mundo'.match(regex)); // Spanish
```

[These](https://github.com/oprogramador/most-common-words-by-language/tree/master/src/resources) wordlists are to be used, and words are to be rewritten entirely using the ASCII characters `A-Z` and `a-z`.  Languages which use characters that cannot be easily transcribed into ASCII without special knowledge or firsthand experience in that language, are excluded.

For instance, the Albanian word `të` is easily transcribed without special knowledge as `te`, so Albanian is allowed.

But the Arabic word `من` cannot be, so Arabic is excluded.

The regular expression must match the language exactly, so appending a list of all languages you are testing before each word is allowed.  But however you organize this list, it must be the same for every word you test.  See the example above for clarification.

### Sandbox Questions

Ideally, brevity of regex, accuracy of language identification, and number of languages taken into account by the regex should all be considered when determining the winner.  But I have not decided on that yet, and am very open to suggestions.

In fact this is my first sandbox post and I hope someone can help me format this properly with good rules so that it makes for an interesting and fun challenge.  I got this idea from some other contest somewhere where the goal was to identify languages with at least 60% accuracy.  But I can't find it anymore.

Comment: So only regex submissions are allowed?

Comment: Although there are options to "weight" the 3 scores differently, the easiest way is to require the other two scores to be larger than some limit (say, at least 2 languages and at least 60%) then compete for the shortest regex.

Comment: Also, are there any similar challenge before?

Comment: Yes, only regex is allowed.  A very similar challenge I've found is this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49596/is-that-word-feminine-or-masculine

Comment: Also this one, which is linked in the other: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42206/distinguish-between-masculine-and-feminine-nouns-in-french-within-100-characters

Comment: Pretty similar. But the huge size of the word list will make the solutions different.

Comment: you should specify a particular flavor of regex.

Comment: I would have said JavaScript but I thought there could be a winner for each programming language?

Comment: If you decide to restrict to 2 languages, you may ask for a regex that matches words from list 1 and not match words from list 2. (it may (do anything|never matches) the words that are not in lists)

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that.

Answer (score -1):

## Rage Against the Dying of the Light

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

## Introduction

"Do not go gentle into that good night" is the title of a poem by 20th century English poet [Dylan Thomas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_Thomas) If you've heard it before it was probably because you watched [Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)), where it was quoted multiple times.

## Challenge

Your program (or function), if it chooses to not go gently, should take no input and print the following text, with an optional trailing newline:

```
Do not go gentle into that good night,
Old age should burn and rave at close of day;
Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

Though wise men at their end know dark is right,
Because their words had forked no lightning they
Do not go gentle into that good night.

Good men, the last wave by, crying how bright
Their frail deeds might have danced in a green bay,
Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

Wild men who caught and sang the sun in flight,
And learn, too late, they grieved it on its way,
Do not go gentle into that good night.

Grave men, near death, who see with blinding sight
Blind eyes could blaze like meteors and be gay,
Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

And you, my father, there on the sad height,
Curse, bless, me now with your fierce tears, I pray.
Do not go gentle into that good night.
Rage, rage against the dying of the light.
```

This is [code-colf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-colf), so smallest code in bytes wins.

## Sanbox

- Is this too bland/simple of a challenge? There's a lot of potential for compressing the poem, but it's not really complex.

Comment: Just be careful it isn't marked as a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i)

Comment: Is the string being different not enough?

Comment: I hope this one is different enough. Things like this are usually borderline since there are several lyrics question closed but some are still open.

Comment: Despite some interesting repetition in this poem, I think the text compression methods used would be the same, making it a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

## Find the nth positive integer m for which \$\tan(m) > m\$ [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

### Task

Write a program/function that when given an integer \$n\$ as input outputs the \$n\$th positive integer \$m\$ for which \$\tan(m) \gt m\$.

**Note:** \$m\$ is in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins.

### Sample Testcases

```
# n -> m
1   -> 1
2   -> 260515
3   -> 37362253
5   -> 534483448
9   -> 214112296674652
10  -> 642336890023956
16  -> 4285797387061825747646013
```

Find more at [A249836](https://oeis.org/A249836)

---

Inspired by [What is the biggest tangent of a prime?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7eJb8n8zAw)

Comment: +1 for referencing a MegaFavNumbers video.

Comment: I don't understand the point. Are you asking us to find the nth number such that `tan(x) > x`? Is there *any* approach that will be shorter than iterating over all numbers until you find the nth number such that `tan(x) > x`?

Comment: Where is `n` in the equation? I'm lost.

Comment: @Razetime On the channel Stand-up Maths, right?

Comment: replace "nth" with "first" "second" etc -> "first/second/etc number m for which ..." i.e. n is not in the equation @V.Courtois

Comment: @Mukundan314 maybe indicate that n is the input?

Comment: @golf69 oh! So it has to be an *integer*, not a *number*. I see now :) And yes, indicating n is the input would be nice.

Comment: I don't really see this being solved any way that taking the generic golfiest code for "find the n'th number meeting [predicate]", of which there's plenty of challenges, and sticking in `tan(m)>m` for the predicate.

Comment: Solutions relying on floating-point arithmetic will get the wrong answer starting around the 11th term. You’ll need to clarify whether that’s acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

## Anti-codegolf, unique characters

### Objective

Write a program/method whose source code's characters are unique. You shall put as many characters as you can.

### Input

There is no input.

### Valid characters

All characters are identified by their Unicode code point. The following characters are invalid, and shall not appear in the source code nor the output:

- C0 and C1 control characters (U+0000 – U+001F and U+0080 – U+009F) except Character Tabulation (U+0009), Line Feed (U+000A), Line Tabulation (U+000B), Form Feed (U+000C), Carriage Return (U+000D), and Next Line (U+0085)

  - Outputting these characters are banned, even if they have special effect on an output stream.
- Low and High surrogates (U+D800 – U+DFFF)
- Noncharacters (U+FDD0 – U+FDEF, and U+xxFFFE and U+xxFFFF for xx = 00 – 10)
- Code points that are outside of U+0000 – U+10FFFF

A character is valid otherwise. In particular, whitespaces, combining characters, and private uses, and even **reserved characters** are valid.

### Restrictions and output

Your program shall halt.

The output shall be a string. This includes string returned by a function, or string printed to `stdout`, `stderr`, a file, or a dialog box.

The set of the characters in the source code shall be a subset of the set of the characters in the output. Note that the output doesn't need to consist of unique characters.

The output may be arbitrarily many strings, for which their concateration will be considered for the restriction above.

### Scoring

This is an anti-codegolf. The submission with the longest source code wins.

Comment: Can we output though an error message?

Comment: @Adám I'd permit it.

Comment: Explicitly stating the range of valid codepoints would be useful.

Comment: So then any expression that generates an error message containing the offending line, followed by a comment symbol and all the unneeded characters, would be the perfect solution?

Comment: @Adám Welp. Then I should add a restriction.

Comment: Be careful about that restriction. Putting restrictions on code is notoriously difficult to get right.

Comment: Also, the languages whose inline comment starts with single char (say Python's `#` or APL's `⍝`), or any esolangs that ignore non-commands will likely get perfect score on any task solvable in that language.

Comment: Not only that, many languages could probably just use an unfinished string (i.e. missing the closing quote)  containing all the other necessary characters.

Comment: @Adám What about now?

Comment: Did you intentionally remove the requirement that the output be longer than the input?

Comment: What are "Reserved characters"?

Comment: @Adám Yes. I tried to find a better restriction.

Comment: @Adám Reserved characters are code points that are not assigned a unicode character.

Comment: Please list the reserved characters (or even better, list all the characters we need to *include*). I believe this changes over time, so you would want to make a definitive specification here.

Comment: The meaning of "The output shall be a string" is unclear. E.g. what does this mean for programs that print to stdout? What about languages without a string type? Be careful not to make assumptions about language features.

Comment: In all likelihood, solutions will have to output the backspace character. It is likely that printing this character has the effect of deleting the previously printed character. Does this count as outputting both characters (the deleted one and backspace)?

Comment: @Adám Why do you think "solutions will have to output the backspace character."? Is this challenge really that hard? I'd say, if outputting backspace character effectively erases a character from the stream, both characters are not counted.

Comment: Ah, good point, but then again, if the goal is to print a subset, then simply including a backspace character in a program that otherwise just echoes itself, is enough to solve the challenge.

Comment: You've now banned line breaks. Lots of languages will have problems using only one-liners.

Comment: So graphical output of text is not allowed? This means that in-browser JavaScript cannot participate, since its only option would be to pop up an alert box. Also, graphical languages like Scratch would be disqualified.

Comment: @Adám Let me return to this tomorrow. I'm tired...

Comment: No problem. Sleep well!

Comment: [code-bowling].

Comment: In any case, the challenge is almost the same as "write a program that prints every Unicode characters" in a language with single-character comment delimiter.

Comment: `"<infinitely many characters here><string implicitly terminated by end of program>`

Answer (score -1):

## Gray codegolf

The [gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is a binary numeral system such that two successive values differ in only one bit.

```
Decimal Binary  Gray
0       0000    0000
1       0001    0001
2       0010    0011
3       0011    0010
4       0100    0110
5       0101    0111
6       0110    0101
7       0111    0100
8       1000    1100
9       1001    1101
10      1010    1111
11      1011    1110
12      1100    1010
13      1101    1011
14      1110    1001
15      1111    1000
```

## Challange

Print the first `k` Gray code numbers, starting from `0`. The shortest code wins!

You may choose the output format as long as it's human-readable.

## Similar questions

- [Give me the Gray Code list of bit width n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32871/give-me-the-gray-code-list-of-bit-width-n) This question is not a code-golf and has different output requirements
- [write a code the find n-th number of Gray Code list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/write-a-code-the-find-n-th-number-of-gray-code-list) This question is a code-golf(at some point) but only asks to output one number

Comment: Why the strict output format, and why the arbitrary constant limit of 1000 (not taking an input number)? Also, [possible dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32871/78410).

Comment: When you say first 1000, is that decimal or binary?

Comment: The challenge I linked *is* code golf.

Comment: @Bubbler nvm, it looks like I am banned from posting lol

Comment: printing a sequence and finding a number in a sequence tend to be very similar tasks.

Answer (score -1):

## B-a-NaN-a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

[Somewhat famously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57456236/8507259), `'B' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a'` returns `BaNaNa` in Javascript. You goal is to output precisely `BaNaNa`. However, to keep it more in the style of the original Javascript, you may not use:

- The bytes 78 or 110
- Whatever `n` or `N` are encoded as if your language uses a special encoding, or
- Any string literal containing the characters `n` or `N`

in your source code.

As a special note, I'd like your feedback as to if restricting numeric literals equal to 78 and 110 would be any good.

Additionally, this is my first question, and I'm aware that 'Do X without Y' is officially not super popular these days, but I frankly quite enjoy them, so I have no idea if this will be well-received or not. I'm hoping that the reference to the JS quirk is enough to make it interesting.

Comment: Restricting numeric literals would just result in `77+1` or `+"78"` or whatever trivial workarounds, so I don't particularly think it's a good idea. For the challenge itself, I don't know if it'll be well-received either. (For the record, `BaNaNa` = `Barium Sodium Sodium` = atomic number `56 11 11`.)

Comment: Since this is such a short string composed only of letters, it's very, very simple to work around it. You need a better restriction method. See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203524/conways-monster), and the questions in [tag:restricted-source]

Comment: Indexing into custom character sets will make this trivial.

Comment: JS, 11 bytes: `\`Ba${+"a"}a\``

Answer (score -1):

## Is it a Pythagorean triple? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Given three numbers, determine whether they form a primitive [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). Here is the definition:

- all three numbers are positive integers
- they represent the side lengths of a right-angled triangle, that is, \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$ for any ordering of \$a\$, \$b\$, and \$c\$
- no other primitive Pythagorean triple exists with the same ratio of side lengths, that is, they are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). For example, \$[6, 8, 10]\$ is **not** a *primitive* Pythagorean triple, even though it satisfies the above conditions, because the simper \$[3, 4, 5]\$ exists.

### Rules

- Unless your language doesn't support them, you must accept floating-point numbers (even though Pythagorean Triples use, by definition, integers)

  - **meta**: Is this necessary? Is it too restrictive?
- You may be given negative numbers, \$0\$, or numbers that cannot form any triangle (right-angled or not, i.e. \$a + b \le c\$), in which cases you must return false.

  - **meta**: Is this necessary? Does it make it too difficult?
- You can return any two distinct individual values, or any typical truthy/falsey values for your language.
- Standard I/O and loophole rules apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest function or full program in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

```
[0, 3, 3] => false
[3, 4, 5] => true
[5, 3, 4] => true
[3, 4, 6] => false
[3, 4, 10] => false
[6, 8, 10] => false
[3.0, 4.0, 5.0] => true
[3.1, 4.0, 5.0] => false
[-3, -4, -5] => false
[3, 4, -5] => false
[4.5, 6, 7.5] => false
[91, 60, 109] => true
[264, 265, 23] => true
[81, 210, 184] => false
[140, 221, 83] => false
```

---

### Meta

- Are the first two rules necessary, or do they restrict it too much?
- Is it clear enough? Are there any additional rules I need to add? Are more test cases needed?
- Does this suit the [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) and [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) tags? It's kind of tangential to both areas.
- Is this [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) too similar to the existing [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions that want you to *generate* triples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146059/80214)

Comment: @Razetime that challenge appeared on the front page today and inspired me to make this one. I thought it was different enough because of the coprime requirement and I added the extra rules about invalid values/floats to make it more interesting as well

Comment: Input validation tends to make for a challenge that is less fun. The coprime requirement is nice, but I'm not sure if it completely changes the challenge.

Comment: This seems to me to be too much a combination of two separate generic tasks, checking that `a^2+b^2=c^2` when sorted, and that `a` and `b` are relatively prime.

Answer (score -1):

## Am I A Perfect Two Integer?

A “perfect two integer” is an integer that works as x in the following equations:

```
Let i = integer, j = integer, x = perfect two integer:
2^i = x
j^2 = x
```

Example “perfect two integers”:
`4`, `16`, `64`, `256`, `1024` (see a pattern here?)

Your answer should take a number from stdin or an argument. This should be relatively easy, but this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins. (Note: there are ways to simplify these equations that aren’t listed here).

---

### Sandbox Questions:

1. Is this a duplicate?
2. Is this too easy?
3. Any other thoughts?

Comment: My personal feeling is that this is too easy. There's not really much scope for golfing the answer once you find the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. It's kind of just like if it's a power of 4. I somehow didn't think about this while making the question.

Answer (score -1):

## Undecidable halting set

Write a program such that the set of [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) on which it halts is not [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set).

Shorter is better.

You may assume natural numbers in your language are unbounded.

### Example: Python 3 (52 chars)

```
lambda n:eval(n.to_bytes(n.bit_length()//8+1,'big'))
```

Comment: This boils down to "emulate a Turing-complete language", which is the same as eval in any Turing-complete language that supports the feature (as you already showed in the example). I don't think it's an interesting challenge.

Comment: @Bubbler Eval is only half the battle (assuming the language has eval in the first place). You still need to handle the fact that the inputs are natural numbers, not arbitrary strings. That is, you need to surject the natural numbers onto a set of strings sufficient to get the undecidable behavior under eval.

Comment: @Bubbler I'd consider an eval-free version of the challenge though, if you have any suggestions. Not sure how that restriction is usually phrased/enforced.

Comment: Eval is half of the battle, but the other half is converting a natural number to a string, which is just a matter of base conversion (which gives ALL strings, maybe except strings starting with null bytes, which doesn't matter in most languages). Unfortunately, banning built-ins is discouraged, and we already had [a challenge about simulating a different Turing-complete language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111278/78410), so I don't think banning eval will make the challenge better.

Comment: @Bubbler Is banning [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) not an objective [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) criterion, as opposed to “no built-ins”?

Comment: Banning built-ins means banning a specific feature of a language, like some old challenge banned exponentiation. It is different from restricted source, which is about restrictions in the source code as text, not looking at the features it uses. There are various classes of eval, e.g. interpret the whole language (Python's exec), interpret the subset of the language (Python's eval and ast.literal_eval), interpret a different language (you can't even count how many Turing-complete mini languages are out there; if Perl regex is Turing-complete, would you ban it?), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the problem, for which I can only think of an iterative solution and have not found a closed formula.

This problem was found on : https://www.codingame.com/ in the `shortest code`mode.

```
You need to paint a house with R rooms.

For each room there are four walls and one ceiling, which all have the same dimensions and need C coats of paint.

You can't paint the next coat until the previous one has dried. You're finished when every wall is dry. Time taken to move between walls, ceilings, rooms is negligible.

It takes you M1 minutes to paint each coat, and M2 minutes for the paint to dry on each. You must finish in the least possible time, otherwise they will not pay you.
```

NOTE DON'T FORGET, THE PAINT MUST ALL BE DRY BEFORE YOU CAN RECEIVE YOUR PAYMENT!

In :

```
Line 1: R, C, M1, M2 separated by spaces.
R: Number of rooms in the house
C: Coats of paint needed for each wall/ceiling
M1: Minutes taken to paint each coat
M2: Minutes taken for paint to dry on each coat (measured from when you've finished the entire coat)
```

Out :

```
The time taken to paint the entire house in the format H:MM
```

Contraints

```
1 ≤ R ≤ 10
1 ≤ C ≤ 20
1 ≤ M1 ≤ 10000
1 ≤ M2 ≤ 10000
```

Dataset:

input: 1 1 12 0

output: 60

input: 5 2 5 30

output: 280

input: 1 5 5 200

output: 1045

Comment: Is this a problem from another site? If so, you need to state where the problem comes from. Also, unlike other online judge sites, we tend to allow submissions to be functions or full programs, and [allow a wide range of I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/78410) for both. Having to convert the minutes to hours/minutes and format as `h:mm` is not so related to the core (and requiring such formatting is discouraged on our site), so I suggest to simply output a number in minutes.

Comment: @Bubbler I have taken your remarks into consideration. I hope it's what you expected.

Comment: Do you have permission to repost this challenge? [CodinGame's rules](https://www.codingame.com/rules) state (Article 9): 'The reproduction, representation or use of all or part of the components proposed in the CodinGame Contests is strictly prohibited.'

Comment: Posting a challenge from elsewhere so that you can be shown an answer is engaging with this community in bad faith. You can ask for programming help in places such as SO, but this isn't intended to be one of them.

Comment: @xnor I am not acting in bad faith or such. I found this problem interesting and I wanted to share with the community to find an optimal answser.
There is nothing for me it this except extending my own knowledge as well as community knowledge

Answer (score -1):

## Hello World! - Generation 3392

Your job is to create a genetic algorithm that slowly evolves and mutates its string until the output is equivalent to "Hello World!".

The genetic algorithm should start with a random string generated, and continue for generations, making random mutations to its code, like this:

```
Gen 3393 - Hemmo World!
```

To:

```
Gen 3394 - Hemko World!
```

## Heres how the randomization algorithm works:

1. Create a function named randint(n), import the time module.

```
# Written in Python 3.8
import time # imports time
def randint(n): # create function
```

2. Get the current time since Jan 1. 1970, multiply by n and assign it as var "t". Make t an integer not a float.

```
t=int(time.time()*n) # Set time, and multiply by n.
```

3. Use the "%" operation on var "t" (var t is the first argument), with var n as the second argument, assign it as "rand".
   Code in python should look like this:

```
rand=t%n #setup a psuedorandom number, since you already have a counter, use n as the limit number, and reset the counter once the counter reaches the limit number. This generates a psuedorandom number within n.
```

4. Return rand.

```
return int(rand) #return results as integer.
```

## Your program should have:

- A randomized start string (using the rand_int algorithm)
- A point it reaches "Hello World!"
- Mutation, using "parents". You are not allowed to completely change a string, only modify 1 character each generation.
- Mutations are not allowed to be repeated twice/No mutation backtracking.
- Once a genetic algorithm has a correct letter in its correct position (such as "e" in "reJ" and "Hes"). It is forced to stay as that letter in that position and the genetic algorithm is forced with that string forever, this repeats for all other positions. This way the time increases additionally instead of exponentially.
  So you cannot do this: ["Hlllr" -> "Hellr" -> "Hfllr"]

So I can do this:

```
Herlo Wcrld
```

```
Herlo Wrrld
```

But you cannot change >1 character/byte at a time:

```
Herto Wcrld
```

```
Heflo World
```

You can do whatever else you want with it if it satisfies those requirements.

## Scoring:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: For code golf to work, the rules must be **very** clearly defined. At the current state people will do `do (s:=randomString()); while(s!="Hello world!"); print(s); ` (pseudocode): (you can make this a popularity contest, but that's even harder to get right. I don't know why)

Comment: @user202729 I want the person to make a genetic algorithm, where it starts with a random string. mutates the previous string randomly by 1 character during each generation,  and eventually outputs "Hello World!"

Comment: Besides being poorly-defined, it is also  an [non-observable behavior](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/69850).

Comment: No, (hey, that's a link. Read it.)

Comment: Wait, that's not what I mean. I'll explain it later.

Comment: @user202729 Right...

Comment: But if the mutations between generations are random, there's no guarantee that the program will ever generate a specific string. You have to add a constraint like *"the program should not generate a given string twice"*

Comment: @Davide I think that rule already existed in the "A point it reaches 'Hello World!'" but I'll add that anyway.

Comment: A few things that I find missing from the rules: How long is the string? How do you mutate space/punctuation marks? I agree that is has non-observable behavior, because you can't see it mutating the string. Does the code have to be in python? Why should it randomize its input and why should it be random during the process? Wouldn't it be better if you get a string from user input (defined length) and then transform it to "Hello World!" (because that would allow bf and other languages to work)

Comment: @Deadbeef 1. The length of hello world, 2. It works with base 64, 3. No, 4. Because I liked it that way. 5. I do not know.

Comment: Okay, about the unobservable behavior, what I mean is...

Comment: It's relatively hard to define what exactly "having a string stored internally" means (what if the string is stored as a list of int values (char codes)? What about encoded in the exponent like in FRACTRAN?) Instead, you can require the programs to output the generations (i.e., **print** the random strings, each subsequent string has one character changed, etc.) [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Answer (score -1):

## Return all elements around an index forming sun

Define a function that takes in a 2D array and a 2D index, and return all the elements of the 2D array that are directly vertical to, horizontal to, and diagonal to the given index, and the returned list must omit the index itself.

External modules, like numpy, as allowed. The most efficient program wins.

[image]

Comment: ... while we do have [fastest-code] on this site, there are specific requirements; restricting allowed programming languages is another problematic thing;

Comment: besides, this definitely sounds like that you're outsourcing your homework to this site.

Comment: @user202729 I already have a numpy solution... this is definitely not homework XD

Comment: @user202729 Okay, removed language restriction.

Comment: Okay, the other problem is with "most efficient code win". Code golf is popular around here because it's easy to measure, but with this you have to install all sort of weird programming languages on a test machine.

Comment: I don't think this is very interesting to do fastest code anyway, because it can be done in linear time anyway (with the array given); besides the general consensus is to allow "full program or function" [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 Okey.

Answer (score -1):

## Create a Screw

There are a variety of [code cad](https://kurthutten.com/blog/curated-code-cad/) languages, as well as other 3d API's that allow you to define shapes with code. Some of these are limited, while others are Turing complete and/or use a popular programming language such as Python or JavaScript.

## The Challenge

Output a 3d model of a screw. Acceptable formats include .stl files and .obj files. A screw is defined as a shorter, wider cylinder on top of a taller, thinner cylinder, which should be threaded at least 5 times. Winner is whoever has the shortest code by two weeks after this question is posted. Standard rules and loopholes apply, with the exception that anything that allows you to programmatically define a 3d object is treated as a program language.

---

---

## Changes

Should I add a spot for the screw driver to my definition of a screw? On the one hand, that would be more realistic, but on the other, it might just add bloat to answers, since I don't think there's anything interesting you can do with it.

I plan to include an example of a minimal screw under whatever definition I end up using, with pictures and outputs in every allowed format.

For the purpose of sorting and answer headers, should each langauge/framework combo be treated as a separate language? I'm leaning towards this, since It would be cool to have an easily searchable set of code for a bunch of different frameworks.

Comment: While the challenge is probably clearly defined enough, it might not allow solutions more interesting than hardcoding compressed output.

Comment: How could I make sure that it does without fundamentally changing it? Or do you think that's not possible? I feel like there might be some potential for interesting ways of doing the threading, but I haven't used very many of these languages..

Comment: No idea... I think that (1) if there's a lot of boilerplate in the file format, using a library might be shorter (2) if the *structure* of the output file is not very repetitive, computing the coordinates might be shorter than hard coding + compressing it. I'm not familiar with either file format so I can't tell. -- -- nevertheless the challenge is on-topic; what I've said only concerns whether it's interesting [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: I think both formats basically just contain the points for every triangle used to represent the 3d object. To be honest I didn't really think about directly creating the file. Compared to using a library, it seems incredibly inefficient. That could make for an interesting challenge on it's own, though...

Comment: You should probably add a specific diagram with the proportions for the screw, or maybe ask the program to take it as input

Comment: @Razetime There's no specific proportion, just "larger" and "smaller".

Answer (score -1):

## Print your PPCG avatar

This is a graphical output question.

You have to connect to the `codegolf.stackexchange.com` in your homepage, scrape and download your avatar and show it in your default image viewer or some other way.

Standard loopholes apply, connections only allowed to `codegolf.stackexchange.com`

One language can be only used once, but a user can post multiple answers in different language

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output),[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

Comment: This is probably a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/137957/31625). Finding the avatar instead of the id wouldn't affect most of the code. Your final line is odd, do you mean that if I answered in a language it would prevent anyone else from using that language? That seems like a bad rule - what if I started on my answer and someone posted while I was working? I can't see any benefit, but perhaps I am not understanding.

Comment: I think it would be interesting if you have  to print the ascii representation of the user before you , without scraping. With a standard way to produce the ascii image so people can't differ. i.e. [img to ascii](https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/convert-images-to-ascii-art/go/)

Answer (score -1):

## Output function from one to another

> I tried to post this twice and I gained negative feedback, so I will put what I have in mind here if anyone is interested.

Get a certain output function from one programming language and transfer to another. You'll be recreating an output function that came from a different programming language. There is a certain criteria in order for the answer to be valid:

1. **It should function the same way as the original function.** All things that function can do should be applied to the recreated one. For example, Python's `print()` has certain keywords like `end`.
2. **Syntax doesn't matter.** Example, if you can't use the `<<` for `cout`, don't use it. Use what's available.
3. **The function should be able to output the same errors like the original.** Replicate the same errors from the original function. If impossible, leave it out.

An answer example would be making `printf()` from C using Python or making `Console.WriteLine()` (or just `WriteLine()` if incapable) from C# using Ruby. Any output functions that are already similar to 2 languages don't need to be replicated in any of them.

Comment: "Get a certain output function from one programming language and transfer to another." To clarify, is the challenge to write source code which works in two different languages and does the same thing? What's the winning condition because this sounds very trivial. For example, `print` does the same thing in many languages.

Comment: Actually that doesn't mesh with "syntax doesn't matter". The point of this challenge is completely unclear, could you please clarify it?

Comment: I see you edited this post but the point of the challenge is still completely unclear. What exactly would a valid submission look like?

Comment: I don't really get the point of this task. Sure, someone could write code that does this, it might take some work to get exactly right, but is there a challenge underneath it? Is it code golf?

Comment: @xnor It isn't code golf, nor king of the hill. It's an ordinary coding challenge if they can replicate a function from one language to another.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe That's not really a thing on this site -- challenges need to have an [objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305/20260). From the close reason: "Questions without an objective primary winning criterion are off-topic, as they make it impossible to indisputably decide which entry should win."

Answer (score -1):

See who can write the *longest* code in order to print "Hello World!". The rule is that if you remove any single character from the code, it should NOT run.

Comment: I think we have a similar challenge already. It's pretty easy to get an infinite score with these rules.

Comment: It is a weaker version of [Programming in a Pristine World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63433/78410) and a different variant of [Biggest Irreducible Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824/78410). But note that, in many languages, it is possible to add arbitrarily long no-op code that breaks when exactly one char is removed. For example, Python's `''+''+''+...` causes syntax error when any of `'` or `+` or a newline surrounding it is removed.

Answer (score -1):

## Random Roman Numerals

Printing a random number is easy, but what about roman numerals? Your task is to output a random roman numeral from 1 to 1000, both inclusive.

Requirements:

- Each number has to have the same chance of appearing
- The program should use the language's random module or other random algorithm

Remember, I is 1, II is 2, III is 3. V is 5, X is 10, L is 50, C is 100, D is 500, and M is 1000. Also note that IV is 4, IX is 9, XL is 40, XC is 90, CD is 400, and CM is 900. For more information see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

This challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to have the shortest program possible!

Comment: I'd really recommend loosening the restrictions for the random numbers. What if the language's random module doesn't guarantee exactly equal chances? Can we assume it does? What about an implementation of an algorithm typically used by language's random modules, like xorshiro or the mersenne twister? A much better restriction in my opinion would be requiring that every result is possible, and it's unlikely people will deviate too far from a uniform distribution anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you're [combining two or more unrelated core challenges into one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319) ― consider splitting the challenge up into separate challenges ― or dropping unnecessary parts. Just watch out for duplicate challenges: [tag:random] number generation and [Roman numeral conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/797/roman-numeral-converter-function) are popular tasks.

Answer (score -1):

## Is this an one-one function?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [set-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory), [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)

---

Two sets given as input, one is the domain of a function, and other one is the co-domain of a function. As an example

$$
\{1,2,3,4\}
$$
$$
\{5,6,7,8,9\}
$$

Now if the range set of the function, i.e. set of each element in the co-domain set which maps to the domain set (`1 -> 5, 2 -> 6, ......`) is equal to the co-domain set, then it is a one-one function.

For the above example, the range set is

$$
\{5,6,7,8\}
$$

So the range set is not equal to co-domain set, the function is not a one-one function.

## Challenge

Inputted two domain and co-domain set of function, output a truthy value if the function is one-one or falsey if not.

## Test cases

```
{1,2,3,4} {5,6,7,8,9} -> Falsey
{a,b,c} {b,c,d} -> Truthy
{4,8,2} {3,4} -> Falsey
```

Standard loopholes apply, [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins

Pre-defining the input sets in the header section of TIO is not allowed.

Comment: Is this challenge simply asking if the two sets have equal length? If not, can you include counterexamples?

Comment: @water_ghosts yes i feel it is like that

Comment: not particularly interesting

Answer (score -1):

## Remaking Kernel [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I made a program as a final project in the main CS50 Harvard course, and it was named Kernel, written in C alsongside CS50's library.

### Functions

It has 7 functions: 4 main (talk, count, calculate, build) and 3 advice functions (error, feedback, help).

What each function does:

- **Talk** asks for a prompt to the user and outputs the same thing.
  [image: Talk Function]
- **Count** asks for a number to count from 1 to there. If the number is bigger than 50, it will lead to an error.
  [image: Count Function]
- **Calculate** asks for 2 numbers and an operator (must be either `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`) then will calculate the value. If the result is a number is greater or equal to `999999999`, it leads to an error. However, `0 / 0 = 0` and other division rules still apply.
  [image: Calculate Function]
- **Build** asks for a size and something that it can build, which could be either a line, tower, wall, or pyramid. If the size is more than 20, it leads to an error. It would then ask for the character you want to use to build it, then it will be used to build the final product. There are multiple errors here, which is explained at the **Error** function.

  [image: Build Function]*Disappointed that I can't make a proper pyramid.*
- **Error** is a library that shows all 14 errors, which is listed in the Error page of this post.
- **Feedback** asks for feedback from the user and they can type whatever they want. The input will then be transferred in a new file called `Feedback.list`.

[image: Feedback Function]

Inside `Feedback.list`: [image: What's in here?]

- **Help** displays the info of the entire app.
  [image: Help Function]

### Errors

There are 14 written errors to prevent writing the real errors.

1. `NO_FUNCTION_ADDED`: When asking for which function to use, entering a non-existent one will result to this error.
2. `ERROR_CLASS_NONE`: In **Error**, entering a number which doesn't have its error will pop this up.
3. `COUNT_MAX`: Well, typing a number greater than 50 won't put up the error, but counting up to 50 will.
4. `INVALID_DIVIDE`: Anything divided by `0` in **Calculate** (except `0 / 0`) will put up this error.
5. `ExTREME_VALUE`: In **Calculate**, earning a final number of `999,999,999` or more will result to this error.
6. `OVERSIZE_CHUNK`: Entering a size larger than `20` in **Build** will result to this error.
7. `UNKNOWN_STRUCTURE`: Also in **Build**, inputting a structure unavailable will pop this up.
8. `UNCLEAR_INSTRUCT`: If the input for **Build**'s line is not vertical, horizontal or diagonal, they wouldn't know what it is.
9. `OVERWIDTH_COUNT`: **Build**ing a tower with a width of 20 or more is invalid.
10. `INVALID_PYRAMID`: Similar to **Build**'s line, inputting a pyramid unavailable pops this up.
11. `OPERATE_BAD`: Inputting an operator unavailable in **Calculate** is invalid.
12. `MORE_NAMES`: If you didn't know, to run Kernel, you need to add your name alongside running it. Me, I use `./Kernel MarkGiraffe`. If I use `Mark Giraffe` instead, it is invalid.
13. `SECRET_USER`: Even NOT putting a name is not allowed.
14. `BAD_ALIGNMENT`: Not choosing left or right for a diagonal line in **Build** is invalid.

For this challenge, I want *you* to remake the program the most designed way, while still keeping low bytes.

In case you are interested, I will post the source code somewhere where you can view it.

Comment: This has LOTS of quality issues. 1) Being a multipart challenge with unrelated subtasks. 2) Rigid I/O (command line arguments AND interactive stdin/stdout AND file output). 3) Input validation and error handling in arbitrary ways. 4) Lack of specification in certain cases. 5) Putting I/O examples in images instead of code blocks.

Comment: I think the outstanding question is, why would people want to code and golf here? Like, it's cool that you wrote a thing, but it seems like a lot of work for someone to re-do on a recreational programming site without a really compelling reason.

Answer (score -1):

## Poly-functional Polyglots

I don't have a ton of time to work on this, so I decided to remove it temporarily while I rework the scoring.

Comment: I think the scoring system is too convoluted. Optimizing for the bonuses seems like more of a challenge than completing the core task. And if number of languages is the denominator, it’s hard to know how to calculate that upfront. How many shells does `echo “Hello World”` work in? If I later learn about another one, does that retroactively lower my score?

Comment: @water_ghosts thanks for saying so. I was worried that that would be the case, especially after reading the discussion on things to avoid in questions. I'm going to try and rework this.

Answer (score -1):

Given a program as input. If the program ever output a '1', output a truthy value and halt; if it halts without ever outputting a '1', output a falsy value and halt; if it falls into infinite loop without outputting a '1', fall into infinite loop.

Comment: This is unclear, for example: what language will the program be in? Do we take it as a string? And for a turing-complete language, this is impossible (at least if it can take input).

Comment: @Wezl Why not??

Comment: You didn't specify the above ^ points, which are important.

Answer (score -1):

## Generate a Printing Program In Some Language

### Task

Given some *rules*:

```
1: Hello
2: World
4: Code
7: Golf
9: Whatever
```

Your program should output a *program* or a *function* (the `output`), which should be a valid program (or function) in some language. When the output is run, it should

1. Ask for some input (`i`),
2. Then output the string in the `i`th index in *rules*. (If there are none, don't output anything - even an error.)
3. Return to step 1.

#### Example:

Rules:

```
1: Hello
5: World
19: Code
```

One possible output (python):

```python
while True:
  i = int(input())
  if i == 1:
    print("Hello")
  if i == 5:
    print("World")
  if i == 19:
    print("Code")
```

### Scoring

Your score is the bytes in your answer (not the output).

---

Obviously this question should be clarified.

Comment: Can we take input as an array of rules (2d, like `[[1, "hello"], [2, "weijfiwef"]]`)? If the index is not in the rules list, can we output an empty string?

Comment: Well I thought about that, but some strong-type languages don't allow different types in a same array. If the index is not in the rules list, you can't output anything (as said in step 2).

Comment: Is my output required to be a full program or it is allowed to be a function?

Comment: Yes @tsh, can be either full program or function.

Comment: Why downvotes? Could you please explain why? I'll improve

Comment: @SketchySketch Not a downvoter, but it seems to be a boring challenge.

Answer (score -1):

Given two reals \$a\$ and \$b\$, output some reals \$r_i\$, such that \$\sum r_i=a\$ and \$\prod\left(r_i+1\right)=b\$. You can assume that it's possible. You can also assume that your float type have infinite precision.

Test cases:

```
2,3 => 2 or etc.
2,4 => 1,1 or 1/2,(sqrt(57)+9)/12,(9-sqrt(57))/12 or etc.
2,5 => 1/3,1/2,2/3,1/2,0 or etc.
2,8 => sqrt(17)+2,2-sqrt(17),-2 or etc.
2,2 => sqrt(2)+1,1-sqrt(2) or etc.
e,2e => 1,e-1 or etc. (e is natural base, though any number>1 work)
-4,9 => -2,-2 or etc.
0,-1 => sqrt(2),-sqrt(2) or etc.
```

Shortest code wins.

## Notes

- Though I only removed two `positive`s from the existing question, it's a huge change to the result.
- I decide to keep the `assume possible` part just to make the note above correct. It can actually be proven that it's always possible.

Answer (score -1):

## Breaking BogoBogoSort (In Badness) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

The title says it all - make a sorting algorithm with a time complexity of \$O(n!^{n!})\$ or higher in the fewest bytes possible - as far as I can tell, that will require you to make a double exponentiatial formula or worse: that is, \$O(a^{b^n})\$, where \$a, b > 1\$.

## Rules (since there must be some)

The list must be returned sorted in a finite time. This can be as high or as low as you want.

The algorithm must work for any real numbers (-30% if you can sort any single type given it's non-mixed).

The algorithm must work of any list length, and must eventually outpace ALL \$O(n!^{n!})\$ formulas, not just BogoBogoSort, and you must state the exact \$O\$ growth rate (for example, \$O(2^{3^n})\$). It may start off slow, but must eventually outpace all other expo-factorial functions (as I now name this growth rate).

Shortest code wins.

Comment: What prevents someone from doing a loop just to make it slower (or calculating \$ n!!!! \$, etc.), and then just sorting the array with quicksort?

Comment: Logic. Logic prevents them from doing something that the question didn't mean you to do. Standart loopholes are forbidden by default

Answer (score -1):

## Get the Collatz Sequence

## The Challenge

Write a full program or function that, when given an integer \$n \ge 0\$, outputs all steps of the Collatz Sequence ([A006577](https://oeis.org/A006577)) of \$n\$.

#### The Collatz Sequence

The Collatz Sequence is defined as:
$$
a(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\text{while n > 1}
$$

#### Input

Input is some integer \$n \ge 0\$.

#### Output

Output is the sequence of numbers visited while calculating the Collatz Sequence, while the output is greater than 1.

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- [Input and output can be in any reasonable format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

#### Test Cases

```
n -> sequence
0 -> [0]
1 -> [1]
2 -> [2, 1]
3 -> [3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
4 -> [4, 2, 1]
5 -> [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
6 -> [6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
7 -> [7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
8 -> [8, 4, 2, 1]
9 -> [9, 28, 14, 7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
10 -> [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
15 -> [15, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
20 -> [20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
25 -> [25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
30 -> [30, 15, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
35 -> [35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
40 -> [40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
45 -> [45, 136, 68, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
100 -> [100, 50, 25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
9329 -> [9329, 27988, 13994, 6997, 20992, 10496, 5248, 2624, 1312, 656, 328, 164, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, 107, 322, 161, 484, 242, 121, 364, 182, 91, 274, 137, 412, 206, 103, 310, 155, 466, 233, 700, 350, 175, 526, 263, 790, 395, 1186, 593, 1780, 890, 445, 1336, 668, 334, 167, 502, 251, 754, 377, 1132, 566, 283, 850, 425, 1276, 638, 319, 958, 479, 1438, 719, 2158, 1079, 3238, 1619, 4858, 2429, 7288, 3644, 1822, 911, 2734, 1367, 4102, 2051, 6154, 3077, 9232, 4616, 2308, 1154, 577, 1732, 866, 433, 1300, 650, 325, 976, 488, 244, 122, 61, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
4637823 -> [4637823, 13913470, 6956735, 20870206, 10435103, 31305310, 15652655, 46957966, 23478983, 70436950, 35218475, 105655426, 52827713, 158483140, 79241570, 39620785, 118862356, 59431178, 29715589, 89146768, 44573384, 22286692, 11143346, 5571673, 16715020, 8357510, 4178755, 12536266, 6268133, 18804400, 9402200, 4701100, 2350550, 1175275, 3525826, 1762913, 5288740, 2644370, 1322185, 3966556, 1983278, 991639, 2974918, 1487459, 4462378, 2231189, 6693568, 3346784, 1673392, 836696, 418348, 209174, 104587, 313762, 156881, 470644, 235322, 117661, 352984, 176492, 88246, 44123, 132370, 66185, 198556, 99278, 49639, 148918, 74459, 223378, 111689, 335068, 167534, 83767, 251302, 125651, 376954, 188477, 565432, 282716, 141358, 70679, 212038, 106019, 318058, 159029, 477088, 238544, 119272, 59636, 29818, 14909, 44728, 22364, 11182, 5591, 16774, 8387, 25162, 12581, 37744, 18872, 9436, 4718, 2359, 7078, 3539, 10618, 5309, 15928, 7964, 3982, 1991, 5974, 2987, 8962, 4481, 13444, 6722, 3361, 10084, 5042, 2521, 7564, 3782, 1891, 5674, 2837, 8512, 4256, 2128, 1064, 532, 266, 133, 400, 200, 100, 50, 25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

## For Meta

- Is it clear?
- Any corrections?

Comment: I'd consider this a duplicate of the [current Collatz challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture-oeis-a006577), as the only way to find the length is to generate the sequence, so the answers will all be doing the same thing, just without a `length` call tacked on the end

Comment: That is what I've always wondered, though, is how we have a *length* of Collatz challenge but not a Collatz sequence generation challenge

Comment: Because there is no way to determine the length of a Collatz sequence without generating it, so the core of the challenges would be the same - generating the Collatz sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Shortest common superstring

Your challenge is to find the shortest common superstring (SCS) for a sequence of English words. The SCS for a sequence is the smallest string that contains all the words in the sequence. The words should be passed as a function parameter.

Answers should be posted in the following format:

```
<Language name>, <Byte count>

<code>
```

This is code-golf, so the answer with the least bytes wins.

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a popularity contest for a task that looks like it can be [tag:code-golf]. However, this is likely a duplicate. caird will be around in a while with a more length message and a link to a dupe :P

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and thank you for using the Sandbox first! Unfortunately, this is a [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11623/66833).

Comment: Ok, well that's fine.

Answer (score -1):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Silly Sentence Generator

Your challenge is to input a sentence and find all words enclosed within angle brackets. (`<` and `>`)

Here is an example:

```
The <adjective> <noun> biked across the bridge.
```

Next, replace all `<noun>`s with a random noun, all `<verb>`s with a random verb, all `<adjectives>`s with a random adjective, and all `<adverb>`s with a random adverb.

According to the above rule, `The <adjective> <noun> biked across the bridge.` *could* become `The daring monkey biked across the bridge`.

Your program will input a list of nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs.

Make sure the words follow capitalization. So if the random noun in `<noun> <verb>ed` is `monkey`, it should then become `Monkey`. Another rule is that if a verb (like `slide`) ends with *e*, and the bit after the `<verb>` is `ing` or `s`, (e. g `<verb>ing`) do not keep the final *`e`*. (e. g slideing becomes sliding).

### Examples

Note that these examples assume the nouns are `monkey` and `ai`, the verbs `jumped` and `sliding`, the adjective `daring`, and any list of adverbs (since the examples don't use them.)

```
The <noun> was <verb>ed by the <adjective> <noun>. => The monkey was jumped by the daring ai.

<verb>ing <noun>s play together. => Sliding monkeys play together.
```

Shortest code wins!

Comment: I would suggest replacing the "Test cases" section with "Examples" to show some possible outputs.

Comment: @AaronMiller Added some test cases and additional rules.

Comment: You don't specify in these cases whether you want to be including the propagation of the word lists, etc. into the code golf challenge.  If this is a requisite that the population of the lists be included in the bytes, this is going to make every 'golfed' solution pretty huge, even with small word lists you've provided.

Comment: @ThomasWard Edited.

Comment: I think it would be better to instead take the lists of words as additional inputs

Comment: It's still not clear if we're hardcoding the words or not

Answer (score -1):

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

## Tac-Tok-Toe

Tac-Tok-Toe is just like tic-tac-toe, but instead of three in a row, the winning condition is *three in a row but each letter is exactly one space apart horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.* The win can also go in *any direction*.

## The games

Each team (X and O) will make their own tac-tok-toe AI's. 10000 games will be played.

## The moves

> AI.PUT_TILE(board: List[List[str]], place: List[int])
>
>     Places a tile at the specified location

> AI.DECIDE_MOVE(board: List[List[str]])
>
>     Decides and returns the index the AI wants to move depending on the current board situation.

> AI.GET_WINNER(board: List[List[str]])
>
>     Returns the winner of the board.

## The board

The starting board looks like this:

```
 | | 
 | | 
 | |
```

(Yes, I know, that indeed is a horrible tac-tok-toe board.)
For example, place [0, 0] is in the upper left square, and place [1, 1] is in the middle. If the X AI places an X at [2, 2], the board would now look like this:

```
 | | 
 | | 
 | |X
```

An example of a completed grid could look like this:

```
X|X|O
O|X|X
O|O|X
```

We see that X has won, so the game should print: "X wins!"

## Game files

[Your side]AI.py:

```python
class [Your side]AI:  # Maybe change to something more meaningful?
    def PUT_TILE(board, place):
        pass
    def DECIDE_MOVE(board):
        pass
    def GET_WINNER(board):
        pass
```

startboard.txt:

```
 | | 
 | | 
 | |
```

**Meta**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that [tic-tac-toe is a solved game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy), you're going to get a lot of near-identical submissions that play perfectly and always end in a draw. Unless you can put some kind of extra spin on tic-tac-toe that makes it more challenging, I'd pick a different game for a KotH. (Maybe one of [these variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe_variants) could work.)

Comment: If you want some tips on writing KotHs with interesting gameplay, check out the [tag:king-of-the-hill] tag wiki!

Comment: Can you explain the win condition a bit better? How can you have 3 in a row with 1 space between them unless the board is 5x5 or larger?

Comment: It can go in different directions.

Answer (score -1):

## Secretary Problem - Cops and Robbers

#### Both threads

(Link to other thread)

The Secretary Problem is a famous problem. In this challenge, it’s a little different:

1. You need a new secretary that asks for the least salary
2. You have a lot of applicants that you can interview one at a time, but don’t know how many applicants there are
3. Each applicant will tell you how much salary they want (they’ll want at least $1 salary, but may all want $5)
4. Applicants do not ever request the same salary for some weird reason (not sure if they’re robots or eavesdroppers)
5. After you interview an applicant, you must give an immediate "yes, I accept you" (truthy) or "no, go away" (falsey)
6. You want the applicant that asks for the lowest salary, so you can stay rich
7. No applicant ever requests more than 1 million dollars (for obvious reasons)

<sub>In the maths world, it’s actually that you want the *highest leveled* applicant, but I put it this way because who doesn’t want to stay rich</sub>

#### Cops Thread

Your challenge is to write a program that takes two inputs: the previous applicants’ salaries, the current applicant’s salary, and outputs whether to accept the applicant (truthy) or deny him/her (falsey).

The robbers will attempt to find a list of applicants (and the salaries they demand) that forces your program to accept a person with a high salary demand. You need to attempt to make your program only accept the applicant which asks for the LEAST salary (that way you can stay rich)

The answer that (when answered against by a robbers thread - [link]) accepts the person with the least salary wins/gets accepted (i.e. the answer that accepts a $1, if that doesn’t exist, then the answer that accepts a $2, if THAT doesn’t exist ... and so on)

If your answer does not accept any, (up to the last applicant) you automatically get

#### Robbers thread

Each answer in the cop’s thread is a program that takes two inputs: the previous applicants’ salaries, the current applicant’s salary, and outputs whether to accept the applicant (truthy) or deny him/her (falsey).

Your challenge is to find a program in the cop’ thread (insert link here) and attempt to give it an input such that it accepts a person with a HIGH salary request. Answer that forces an algorithm to accept the highest amount of money gets accepted (i.e. the answer that forces a cop answer to accept a $1000000 salary applicant, if that doesn’t exist, the answer that forces a cop answer to accept a $999999 salary applicant, if THAT doesn’t exist ... and so on)

Put a link cop answer you are attempting to make go broke in your answer.

You must have at least 100 applicants (with at least one applicant that requests <$100)

#### Both threads (again)

To stop people getting free points, you cannot make a robbers answer for your own cop answer. 1 answer per thread (you can have both a robber answer and a cop answer as long as the robber answer is against a different cop answer)

#### Sandbox questions

- Is this too far-fetched?

[<s>Somewhat shamelessly stolen</s> Derived](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157876/) from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75967)

[cops-and-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-and-robbers)

Comment: If the cop is forced to accept the last applicant if they haven't previously accepted anyone, isn't having exactly one applicant with a salary of $1m an unbeatable strategy for a robber?

Comment: Changed - "at least 100 applicants" and "at least one applicant that requests <$100"

Comment: The cops can consider only the bound of $100, as at least one robber will be <$100.

Answer (score -1):

## Randombility of number

The aim of golf is to calculate score of how random 10 inputs given by users were. The Criteria is given below.

- Points             Rule
- 5+(1.1)^n If inputted numbers are not in Arithmetic OR Geometric progression for n cnsecutive terms
- 5+(1.1)^n if inputted numbers are not strictly increasing or decreasing for n>2
- 5*n   if number is prime number > 100 here n is number of such terms
- -5-(1.1)^n    if number is substring of $\pi$$ (3.1415926535897932384626433) for n>2
- 5 if difference between largest and smallest input is greater than 1000
- -5*n  for n repeated inputs
- -5 + ln(log(p))   if number is square or cube of any number beetween -100 and 100 here p is number
- -5    if any three input ressemble any valid date (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy) time(hh/mm or mm/hh) format

  - -Additional
- (1.5)^n   if time interval between two inputs is less than 1.5 seconds

Improvements required Score system.

Comment: Can you please clarify your challenge? I don't get even the point of the challenge or how to win.

Answer (score -1):

## Output a random integer in a range that is a multiple of all in one set and not a multiple of any in another set

Given an integer range and two sets of integers, generate a random integer inclusive within the range that is a multiple of all the numbers in the first set but is not a multiple of any number in the second set, or specify that such a value does not exist.

### Examples:

- Range: 100 - 200
- Divisors: 3, 5
- Non-divisors: 9, 10

Possible values are: 105, 165, 195 (output one at random)

### Rules

1. Mathematically elegant solutions are preferred, but brute force solutions are accepted.
2. If outputting one of multiple values is possible (as shown above), the solution should return a different value with each execution so that, probabilistically, all possible values are eventually output.
3. This is code golf, so lowest byte count wins.

***NOTE** I have a solution for this in C#, but I'm curious of what other solutions there are.  I had a heck of a time working out the math for this and thought it would be a good bit of puzzling for this community.*

Comment: The First Rule is unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you say so?  If not included, I expect only brute force solutions will be provided.

Comment: If the first code is included and others may think is fastest-code tag

Comment: I suppose that is one of the end goals.  Maybe that's a win condition I need to add.  I've never seen that in code golf.  I'll have to research that tag for examples.

Comment: This needs testcases (pick one at random) and add tag [tag:random].

Answer (score -1):

## Quantum boolean

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [boolean](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean)

### Background

Have you ever dream of quantum state? If that's true for you, you are probably weird...

Anyway, I came up with an idea: what if we make a quantum in code?

### Task

Create a `data type`, `function`, or `class`, anything that can be put in a condition.

What should it do:

```
(def your thing here, I'll name it "X" for now)


if X:
  part a
else:
  part b
```

part a and b should both be executed, although the chance of which being first should be 50/50.

```
if X:
  a=5
else:
  a=10
  b=5
```

`a` should have 50% chance to be `5`, 50% `10`, but `b` will always be `5`

`x` can be different everytime mention, or always the same on *parallel universe*

```
if X:
  part a
else if X:
  part b
else:
  part c
```

Could be:

execute `a,b,c` with `a` 50% being first execute,`b,c` 25% each.(second X and first X both being quantum)

In this case `a` will never be the second one executed.

possible case:

```
a,b,c
a,c,b
b,c,a
c,b,a
```

```
     / a True 50%
init           / b True 25%
     \ a False 
               \ b False - c 25%
     First X     Second X
```

Or:

`X` True for `a`

`X` False for `c`

`b` will never be executed.

```
     / X True - a
init 
     \ X False - c
```

## Example

`X` as your submit

```
if X: # or X()
  print(1)
else:
  print(2)
```

return

```
1
2
```

or

```
2
1
```

## Extra

A whole compiler/transpiler (changing code to fit in quantum state) is allowed, but will compete on it's own(with other compiler style anwser).

## Rule

- Standard rules.

## Goal

golf your quantum as smaller as possible!

## Meta

- Is this clear?
- Is this hard?
- Is this fun?

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. You seem to be describing a code construct that takes a list of statements and executes them all in random order. By design that isn't how `if`/`else` statements work: 'part a and b should both be executed' can't happen no matter how you define `X`.

Comment: @Dingus one of the possible way is to have function `X` read self source code, you don’t have to run excatly same code on excatly position, you can copy statement and execute it at other file/place, or just rerun program with modifications upon called.

Answer (score -1):

## Output sequence from a name

You are given a sequence of numbers(0-9) which you have to convert to its literal form.

### Example

Input : `1246`
Output : `26666`

We interpret the input as `one 2 four 6`, thus giving the output 2 one time and 6 four times

### Testcase

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567809 | 2444666668888888 |
| 2345 | 335555 |

### P.S.

1. Is this descriptive enough?
2. Would it be fun to do?

Comment: This is essentially run-length decoding, which we already have a challenge on: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12902

Answer (score -1):

## Can I obtain this Minecraft item?

Given a list of items I have access to, determine if I can obtain a certain amount of some other item via crafting, mining, trading, and some other actions.

### Actions

This is a list of all actions which may be performed, and what items they involve

**Crafting:**

- Log × 1 to Planks × 4
- Planks × 2 to Stick × 4
- Dirt × 2, Gravel × 2 to Coarse Dirt × 4
- Glass × 6 to Glass Pane × 16

**Mining:**

The following require a wood pickaxe, or above:

- Stone × 1 to Cobblestone × 1
- Coal Ore × 1 to Coal × 1

The following require an iron pickaxe, or above:

- Diamond Ore × 1 to Diamond × 1
- Emerald Ore × 1 to Emerald × 1

The following do not require a tool:

- Coarse Dirt × 1 to Dirt × 1
- Gravel × 1 to Flint × 1

**Smelting:**

Smelting requires fuel, see below. These are the items that can be smelted:

- Cobblestone × 1 to Stone × 1
- Sand × 1 to Glass × 1
- Coal Ore × 1 to Coal × 1
- Iron Ore × 1 to Iron Ingot × 1
- Diamond Ore × 1 to Diamond × 1
- Emerald Ore × 1 to Emerald × 1
- Kelp × 1 to Dried Kelp × 1

(unfinished)

Answer (score -1):

## Biggest 25 byte number

You are allowed 25 bytes of source code.

With these you have to calculate the biggest *finite* number possible, assuming infinite number precision<sup>[1]</sup>, runtime and memory.

You will not be taking input and do **not** have to output the final result.

You are **not** allowed to use a String representation, so `"9".repeat(BIG_NUMBER)` is disallowed.

Scoring will be based of the final number, bigger numbers ranking higher.

[1]: This means that for example in java you do *not* need to use `BigInteger` to represent big numbers, but using an `int` would be sufficient. Over- and underflows are ignored as if the `int` had infinite precision.

Answer (score -1):

## [1], [2], [1, 1], [3, 2] Sequence

### Challenge:

The sequence starts with [1]

And multiply by the reversed indices plus one.

And make an extra list containing 0 length of the list times.

If the number is greater than reversed indice plus two, then modulo by indice plus two, add number integer divided by indice plus two to extra list (Previous indice).

Then the next list will be the list plus an extra list.

### Example (step-by-step)

```
RETURN [1]
[1]
[2] [0]
[2] [0]
RETURN [2]
[2]
[4] [0]
[1] [1, 0]
RETURN  [1, 1]
[1, 1]
[3, 2] [0, 0]
[3, 2] [0, 0]
RETURN [3, 2]
```

## Test cases

TODO

## Meta:

- Suggestions?
- Which test cases I should add?

Comment: Adding more step-by-step examples would be nice. After `[3, 2]`, I can get to `[9, 4]`, but I'm not sure what to do with `[1, 0]` (`[9, 4]` modulo 4) and `[2, 1]` (`[9, 4]` div 4). Also, test cases in a sequence challenge are just a list of first X terms (20 terms would be enough here I think).

Comment: I think a reference implementation (even in pseudocode) would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[Mahjong Checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242582/mahjong-checker)

Comment: As a real mahjong player I can tell you that it may not be enoigh to have four sets and the eye pair – flowers and animals may be needed to win.

Comment: flowers and animals are excluded in this case, makes it a little more tricky to add more possiblities to the challenge

Comment: I know, but this is just for your information.

Comment: ah ok lol thx anyways i rarely play mahjong in the first place

Answer (score -1):

## Zhiwei Sun Squares

Given a positive integer `n`, find the number of ordered tuples `(a, b, c, d, e)` over non-negative integers for which `a² + b² + c² + d² = n` and `b + 3c + 5d = e²`.

Note: A conjecture by 孙智伟 (Sūn, Zhìwěi) states that this count is always at least `1`.

For example, if `n` is 9, there are 3 solutions, namely:

```
(0, 0, 3, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 2, 2, 4)
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

### Test cases:

```
9 -> 3
4 -> 2
24 -> 1
25 -> 5
144 -> 3
128 -> 1
365 -> 9
366 -> 21
```

### Scoring:

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Credits to [this puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/zhiwei-sun-squares)

Answer (score -1):

## The travelling sales man problem

The travelling salesman problem (TSP) asks the following question: "Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities, what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once and returns to the origin city?"

In this puzzle not necessarily the shortest route is the answer but an approximation using a greedy algorithm (which in fact could be the shortest route as well).

This greedy algorithm starts at the first input given and always chooses the nearest point from the current point. This continues until no points are left and the last point is connected to the first point.

Use the Euclidian distance, i.e. `sqrt(deltaX^2 + deltaY^2)`, as the distance between two cities. If there are points with the same distance, always pick the one occurring first in the list.

In general, the greedy algorithm does not find the optimal solution, but nonetheless a greedy heuristic may yield locally optimal solutions that approximate a global optimal solution in a reasonable time.

### Input & Output

- You are given an integer `n` and on the next `n` lines, you are given the x and y coordinate of the city

### Test cases

```
5
9 12
24 15
12 30
4 3
13 27
->
71

5
25 2
5 9
22 12
15 19
0 1
->
69

12
4 5
12 80
65 18
39 29
99 11
84 31
9 9
54 49
16 27
31 67
0 71
60 0
->
403
```

### Others

- You are allowed to take in the input as a list of `n` integers

### Scoring:

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Credits to [this puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/the-travelling-salesman-problem)

Answer (score -1):

## Draw an Erlenmeyer flask

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Given the level of liquid in the Erlenmeyer flask `L` in the range `0-6`. Your program should draw the following ASCII art.

When `L=0`:

```
      __________
     |_        _|
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       /      \
      /        \
     /          \
    /            \
   /              \
  /                \
 /                  \
/                    \
\____________________/
```

When `L=1`:

```
      __________
     |_        _|
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       |      |
       /      \
      /        \
     /          \
    /            \
   /              \
  /                \
 /  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \
/  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \
\____________________/
```

When `L=6`:

```
      __________
     |_        _|
       |      |
       |  %%  |
       |  %%  |
       |  %%  |
       |  %%  |
       /  %%  \
      /  %%%%  \
     /  %%%%%%  \
    /  %%%%%%%%  \
   /  %%%%%%%%%%  \
  /  %%%%%%%%%%%%  \
 /  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \
/  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \
\____________________/
```

You can change the character `%` to any other (excluding space), it's up to you. Trailing spaces are allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Answer (score -1):

## Implement a complex search engine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Your job is to implement a search engine. The search engine should come with a few extra features to ensure that users can obtain the most relevant results.

### Input, part 1

Your program will take a string as input. The string is composed of a bunch of words separated by spaces. Parsing the string is part of the task, so inputting as a list of words will not be allowed.

#### What's a word?

A word is composed of one or more lowercase letters. There may be a minus at the start of the word. If there is no minus, then there can be a double-quote at the beginning and/or end of the word. Double-quotes are closed, so `"abc de` is not a valid input because the double-quote is never closed, but `"abc def"` is valid because the double quote is closed.

#### The minus

A minus at the beginning of a word tells the search engine to not return results that contain that word.

#### Double-quotes

Double-quotes around strings tell the search engine to only return results that contain that string exactly.

#### Extra rules

There will never be any minus words contained within a quoted string. The minuses and quotes will never contradict, so `-abc "abc"` will never be given (it tells the search engine to exclude results containing `abc` while telling it to return only results containing `abc`).

The string contains only minus signs, quotes, spaces, and lowercase letters. There is at least one word that is not excluded by means of a minus.

### Input, part 2

The second input will be a list of strings from which the search engine will search. The strings contain only lowercase letters and spaces. You may take a newline-separated list of strings or a list of strings in your language's native input format, or any other reasonable method to input strings. (Lists of words are not allowed.)

### Output

Return all results matching the input. Your output format can be a newline-separated list of strings, or a list of strings in your language's list format. Lists of words are forbidden.

Any results that it returns must:

- contain all of the unquoted words that do not have a minus, but not necessarily in the given order;
- contain all quoted strings exactly;
- not contain any excluded words indicated by a minus.

### Testcases

```
Search query: abcdefg
List of strings: [abcdefg, abcdef, bcdefg, abcd efg]
Output: [abcdefg]

Search query: blah blah blah
List of strings: [blah, blah blah, blah blah blah, bla hbla h]
Output: [blah, blah blah, blah blah blah]

Search query: "blah blah" blah
List of strings: [blah, blah blah, blah blah blah, bla hbla h]
Output: [blah blah, blah blah blah]

Search query: my name is -not ophact
List of strings: [my name is ophact, my name is not ophact, my name is op, ophact is indeed my name]
Output: [my name is ophact, ophact is indeed my name]

Search query: "oh please help" me or "otherwise someone else"
List of strings: [oh please help me or otherwise someone who is else, oh please otherwise someone else, help me or otherwise oh someone else, or]
Output: []

Search query: -remove -all -the -most -common -words but keep "everything else"
List of strings: [guide how to remove an item from a list, words are the rest, keep everything else but not that, remove all the most common words but keep everything else]
Output: [keep everything else but not that]
```

This challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code, measured in bytes, wins.

---

Any feedback? Clarification needed? Other tags are suitable? Wrong testcase?

Answer (score -1):

## Fort-Defense KoTH

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

There are two teams, red and blue. Each team has a fortress, and if one team's fortress is destroyed, (health reaches zero) the other team wins.

The red team attacks the blue team first, blue attacks red, red attacks blue, and so on until one team's fortress is destroyed. Every team has half of the total number of bots. (For an odd number of bots, one team has one more bot.)

The grid looks like this:

```
FBBBBB|BBBBF
FBBBBB|BBBBF
FBBBBB|BBBBF
FBBBBB|BBBBF
```

where B is a bot, F is the fort, and | as the border between the two teams.

Comment: What would the attacks be like? Right now it doesn't seem like much strategy is involved.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms i know, it isn't finished yet.

Comment: Are you planning on a 2D grid or for attacks to just be an action? If the first option, it would probably make sense for the defenders to be able to "send out" some bots to fight the attackers while others man the fort. If not, the strategy probably has to come from designing your team to work together well and to decide how many resources to allocate to fighting vs. how many for defense.

Comment: @Romanp 2d grid

Comment: You also can choose between real-time and turn-based strategy. There haven't been many RTS KoTHs that I have seen, but it seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: @Romanp Ooh yeah, RTS would mean writing performant bots is a major goal, something that hasn't really been explored. I've proposed an RTS KotH before, but never really did anything with the idea.

Comment: Now I want to make a RTS game, but I'm still running my current KoTH and am planning on a fix/reboot of King of the Ziggurat (if I can get permission)...

Comment: @Romanp whats a RTS?

Comment: Real time strategy. Pretty much, all the bots are moving at once (probably with floating point numbers) and everything is continuous. The bots probably have position/velocity values which automatically move them every tick, that sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

## Roman Numerals... But With A Twist

I'm assuming you have some knowledge of roman numerals, but more is at Appendix A.

Fine. What's the twist?

## I want it short

So, I don't want to express 1 as `IIIIIIIIIX`, I want it `I`.

## And we are not Romans, come on...

Instead, you will create a program that takes in, either as a function parameter or from STDIN:

- A dictionary to represent Roman Numerals. You can take it in any (reasonable) format, for instance: `{"I":1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100}`, `"I1 V5 X10 L50 C100"`, or even `"0111 1011 0010 0010 0100 1001 0010 0010 0011 1010 0011 0001 0010 1100 0010 0010 0101 0110 0010 0010 0011 1010 0011 0101 0010 1100 0010 0010 0101 1000 0010 0010 0011 1010 0011 0001 0011 0000 0010 1100 0010 0010 0100 1100 0010 0010 0011 1010 0011 0101 0011 0000 0010 1100 0010 0010 0100 0011 0010 0010 0011 1010 0011 0001 0011 0000 0011 0000 0111 1101"`. You may cast any assumption on the input format, for instance, the letters must be in increasing order, or the odd numbers come first (even though, come on, why?) Assume all numbers to be positive.
- The number to represent. For instance, 128724235. Assume all numbers to be positive. The number will be guaranteed to be accomplishable. For instance, for the dict `{"A":10,"B":58}`, 2 might be given (which your program should output).

Your output would be the shortest Roman Numeral representation for the given numeral and mapping.

## Example Program:

Up later...

## Appendix A

- The mapping of letters to characters is `{'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10,  'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}`
- Every letter is added or subtracted from a total
- The total is the value of the numeral

For the adding or subtracting, we create the following standards:

- If there is a character that stands for a higher value at the right, for instance an `X` on the right of the `V`, the value of `V` will be subtracted.
- Else, it will be added. for instance, `VV` is 10 and `V` is 5, as there are no higher numbers at the right.

Let's just keep things clear by giving an example:

`10` is `X`, `5` is `V`, `1` is `I`, `6` is `VI`, `4` is `IV`, `2` can be `IIIV`, `19` is `XIX`, `4` can also be expressed as `IVX`. Note the last three.

To make things even clearer this is a decoder:

```python
def roman_to_integer(numeral,mapping=None):
 if not mapping: mapping = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 
  'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}
 result = 0
 for index, character in enumerate(numeral):
  if index+1==len(numeral) or \
   mapping[character]>=max(map(lambda x: 
   mapping[x], numeral[index:])): 
    result+=mapping[character]
  else: result-=mapping[character]
 return result
```

Comment: I suggest specifying clearly with some words (maybe in several bullet-points) the algorithm you use for your definition of Roman numerals.

Comment: Oh OK good point

Answer (score -1):

## Minimal number of moves needed by a knight

---

Given an \$N × N\$ board, what is the minimum number of moves needed by a knight to reach every square (on any given square)?

In other words, the [A232007](https://oeis.org/A232007) sequence from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

Input/Output can be taken in any reasonable format, taking the size of the board and returning the number of moves (you don't need to handle `2`, and `3` because the knight can't travel all of the \$2 × 2\$ and \$3 × 3\$ board)

Testcase:

```
8 -> 6
5 -> 4
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `-1` output, and not requiring answers to handle those inputs. Adding edge cases like this tends to make the challenge quite boring to golf, because a lot of the code gets taken up by them

Comment: Do you mean minimum or maximal?

Comment: I think this may be too simple, as it is just `ceiling(2n/3)` per the OEIS page.

Answer (score -1):

## Left and Right, Spsp Style

##### `WARNING`

This question is written by the Spsp language creator TvoozMagnificent` and might includes severe advertising.

##### Spsp

What's Spsp? Spsp is designed to be a 2D fourth generation golfing language.

##### What are the commands?

Good question, it is in developement, and if you want to help me, come (here)[https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136645/superior-simple]. Thank you.

But three commands have been kept in Spsp and is likely to stay that way. For the Spsp in this challenge, we have simplified things.

The commands are `L`, `R`, and `S`, which stand for `left`, `right`, and `stop`. You will be given a program, for instance this: (You would probably take it as a list instead, for instance `[[' ','R','S'],[' ','L','S'],['L','S',' ']]`) Assume the lines to be padded to the same length.

```
+-+-+-+
| |R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

The `IP`, which stands for the `Instruction Pointer`, Starts out at the top left cell, pointing right, so let's draw it as `>`. Thus, the current map looks like this:

```
+-+-+-+
|>|R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

Now the `IP` tries to advance. It hits an `R` block, so it **doesn't advance**, and turns right. Now it points down:

```
+-+-+-+
|v|R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

Now the `IP` can advance:

```
+-+-+-+
| |R|S|
+-+-+-+
|v|L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

Now the `IP` can't advance again, so it turns left. This is because it points towards an `L`, the `L` at the side has no effect:

```
+-+-+-+
| |R|S|
+-+-+-+
|>|L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

And turns left again to point upwards:

```
+-+-+-+
| |R|S|
+-+-+-+
|^|L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

It advances:

```
+-+-+-+
|^|R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

If the `IP` hits a wall, it raps. (Pun Intended) So if the `IP` advances, he would end up on the `L` marked `X` on this map:

```
+-+-+-+
|^|R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|X|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

And thus the pointer turns left:

```
+-+-+-+
|<|R|S|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

And the pointer advances and hits the `S`:

```
+-+-+-+
| |R|X|
+-+-+-+
| |L|S|
+-+-+-+
|L|S| |
+-+-+-+
```

Thus the pointer stops. Your chllenge is to output the ending coordinate in some way, whether it is the mathematical coordinate system `(2,2)` or the index `[1,3]` or `[0,2]`.

There's a small twist however. What does this program do?

```
+-+-+
| |R|
+-+-+
|L|S|
+-+-+
```

Well, the `IP` turns right, and then turns left, and then... yikes, that's an infinite loop! What do we output then? Well, don't output anything, **but terminate the program instead of running forever**. It is easy to know that if the same `IP` state is achieved twice, then a loop will happen.

Or, take this:

```
+-+
| |
+-+
|S|
+-+
```

The `IP` just wraps around and loops on the first line.

Answer (score -1):

## The prime frog  -- Integrated.

From the [original question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145741/the-prime-frog?rq=1), we make the following changes:

> The "prime frog" is a strange animal that jumps between integers*<s>, until it arrives on 3 or 19...</s>
>
> ---
>
> *<s>Your program should accept an integer `n` as input and output the result of the below algorithm (`3` or `19`)</s>*.
>
> For a given integers `n > 1` and `b > 1`:
>
> 1. Let `f` be the position of the frog. It is initially set to `n`
> 2. if **`f` has been hopped on: return the smallest lilypad hopped after and including the `f` hopped on last time**
> 3. if `f` is prime : the frog jumps to the position **`b×f+1`**. Go back to step 2.
> 4. if `f` is composite : let `d` be `f`'s biggest prime divisor. The frog jumps to the position `f-d`. Go back to step 2.

### Examples:

An example with `n = 5`, `b = 4`:

```
5 > 21 > 14 > 7 > 29 > 117 > 13x8 > 13x7 > 13x6 > 13x5 > 13x4 > 13x3 > 13x2 > 13 (I'm a bit lazy there) > 53 > 213 > 142 > 71 > 285 > 14x19 > 13x19 > snip > 38 > 19 > 77 > 66 > 55 > 44 > 33 > 22 > 11 > 45 > 40 > 35 > 28 > 21 (loop), returns 7.
```

Thus the program should output `7`.

Another example with `n = 23`, `b = 3`:

```
 23 > 70 > 63 > 56 > 49 > 42 > 35 > 28 > 21 > 14 > 7 > 22 > 11 > 34 > 17 > 52 > 39 > 26 > 13 > 40 > 35 (loop), returns 7.
```

Again, the program should output `7`.

### Test cases:

Coming up later

## Meta: is it possible for a number to go up infinitely?

Comment: Downvoters, why?

Answer (score -1):

## Build a file/directory tree

### Task

In this challenge, your task is to write a program or function which takes an array of paths with an additional boolean indicating it is a file or directory and outputs a file/directory tree in **any** reasonable format.

### Remarks

- Some directories can end with a forward slash (**"/"**) but this is not always the case
- A parent directory is not always explicitly defined but should be in the tree
- **"."** and **".."** as file name or directory name are not allowed
- Standard loopholes are not allowed

### Input

An unsorted array of paths. Each item is a tuple of path and a boolean which is True for a file and False for a directory.

```
[
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/', False],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/hello.txt', True],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/SubSub Folder/SubSubSub Folder/', False],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/world.txt', True],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder 2', False],
]
```

### Output

Any output which shows or defines a tree based upon input is valid.

#### Text formatted example

```
[D] Root Folder
    [D] Sub Folder
        [D] SubSub Folder
            [D] SubSubSub Folder
        [F] hello.txt
        [F] world.txt
    [D] Sub Folder 2
```

#### Data structure formatted example

```
[
    'Root Folder',
    [
        [
            'Sub Folder',
            [
                [
                    'SubSub Folder',
                    [
                        [
                            'SubSubSub Folder', [], []
                        ]
                    ],
                    []
                ]
            ],
            ['hello.txt', 'world.txt']
        ],
        [
            'Sub Folder 2',
            [],
            []
        ]
    ],
    []
]
```

This is a code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Meta

- Is this an interesting question?
- Is this question clear enough?
- Anything i can do to improve this question?

Comment: I think it would be good to simplify input and output as much as possible. For example the input being just list of strings and directories identified by ending with slash. And also specifying list of characters which can/can't appear in path would allow to use some of those as string separator (perhaps best as separator would be space and newline). This would mean that data can be easily read from STDIN.

Comment: You should also write a bit about how the algorithm generating the tree works. For example: "You split all paths by character /, which gives you list of directories and possibly file. The you choose first part of any path and output this, then you have to find all paths which begin with the same directory..." (I think it can be written a bit better than I did and also I didn't described it fully) Also then the output can be maybe a bit simplified or a bit better defined too, but I am not sure how (maybe not differentiating between directories and files).

Answer (score -1):

Write a program on any language that accepts some input and give some different output. The challenge is that the text of the program must form a square: all rows must be the same length and the number of rows must equal the number of columns (ie length of rows). Adding extra spaces or comments to pad lines is not allowed.

This is Code Golf so the one with the shortest functioning program (ie smallest square) wins!

Comment: Welcome to the site! To edit your post there is edit button. You have posted two similar versions of same post, so I recommend deleting the older (this one). I will post further recommendations under your new post.

Answer (score -1):

## Convert English to integer

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

When saying a number out loud in English, or writing it out in words, speakers use a certain method.
Since there's lots of variations from person to person on the specific method, I'll define the format I'm using here:

- [TODO]

Some things to note about the format:

- There are no commas, only lowercase letters and spaces.
- There is no "and" separating the hundreds and tens.
- `1234` is described as "one thousand two hundred thirty four", not "twelve hundred thirty four".

[Here's some rather sloppy code that, given a number, generates the associated English phrase.](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ycgqedun)

### The challenge

Taking an input \$s\$ which a string describing some integer \$n\$ written using the format above, output \$n\$. In other words, convert from an English description of a number back to its integer form. Your code should be able to handle string associated with non-negative integers up to but not including a quadrillion (i.e. \$0 \leq n \leq 999,999,999,999\$), or the maximum value that an integer can have in your programming language. You can assume the input will always follow the format above.

### Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `zero` | `0` |
| `eight` | `8` |
| `ten` | `10` |
| `sixteen` | `16` |
| `twenty` | `20` |
| `thirty five` | `35` |
| `one hundred` | `100` |
| `four hundred nine` | `409` |
| `five hundred thirteen` | `513` |
| `seven hundred seventy seven` | `777` |
| `six thousand five hundred thirty four` | `6534` |
| `one hundred thousand ten` | `10010` |
| `twenty four thousand three hundred sixty five` | `24365` |
| `eighty eight million two hundred twenty thousand one hundred` | `88222100` |
| `seven hundred million eleven thousand ninety nine` | `700011099` |
| `eight hundred ninety four billion three hundred twelve million five hundred sixty seven thousand eight hundred ninety one` | `894312567891` |
| `one trillion` | `1000000000000` |
| `five hundred trillion one` | `500000000000001` |

Standard I/O rules apply, standard loopholes are forbidden. The shortest program wins.

### Questions

Do I need to describe the format besides saying how it deals with the major variants (e.g. including/excluding "and")? I really don't want to formally write out all that stuff.
I also don't like the wording of the first sentence at all, but I feel like I need *some* introduction.

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find a duplicate. Here some related challenges though: [closed popcon duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32381/convert-english-to-a-number); [English to number without builtins for 1-100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71681/convert-english-to-a-number-without-built-ins-or-libraries); [calculating with English words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12757/english-numeral-calculator); [string of digit-words to integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/convert-a-string-of-digits-from-words-to-an-integer).

Comment: Can someone give feedback on what's wrong with this challenge?

Answer (score -1):

**find overlap between 2 grids**

You have 2 grids with numbers inside, and you want to find the overlapping parts.

**For example** 
The firdst grid

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

The second grid

```
2 3 4 1
2 3 4 2
9 8 6 4
```

This part is the overlapping part:

```
2 3 4
2 3 4
```

And when you combine, you sould get this:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 1
1 2 3 4 2
  9 8 6 4
```

**Rules**

- The grids are minimum 2*2 and MUST be a rectangle or a square.
- The input can be the size of the grids (and random generated content), or the content of the grids itself (your choice)
- The output can be visual just like my example or sommerhing else (but explain how to read it).
- If there is no overlap you output what you want but it needs to be clear.

**goal**
It is code golf so the byte size is important.

Comment: What do we output if there is no common part, like `1 2 3 newline 4 5 6` and `7 8 9 newline 4 8 3` where newline is a grid row separator?

Comment: Or is the input guaranteed to have at least one overlapping value?

Comment: It needs to be clear, I wouls say domething like "-1" or can be tex or so.

Comment: Won't it be more sensible to output truthy/falsey values for whether there exists overlapping values? That way you can account for all possible inputs.

Comment: Like I statet in the question, "find the overlapping parts", not if there is overlap or not.

Comment: I only suggested it; it's up to you if you want to modify the challenge.

Comment: Do you think it is better to change it? To my logic you have to know if there is overlapping before you know where. So it is part of it.

Comment: So include the expected output for not having overlapping grids

Answer (score -1):

## Find all matrices whose sliding sums are the input

Like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253453/find-a-matrix-whose-sliding-sum-is-the-input), but [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Answer (score -1):

Posted on main: [Make a Compiler or Interpreter for any Turing-complete language in another language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253648/make-a-compiler-or-interpreter-for-any-turing-complete-language-in-another-langu)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange, and thank you for using the sandbox. Wouldn't any language that has an evaluate command perform this task in very few bytes?

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: I generally recommend leaving challenges in the sandbox for a week, especially if the author is new to writing challenges.

Comment: Anyway, when posting to main, edit the sandbox post to just a link, and delete it.

Answer (score -1):

## [RGB to Hexadecimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254081/rgb-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: Instead of `0 < r < 255 (both inclusive)`, which is a bit of a nonstandard way to write that, why not MathJax: \$0\lex\le255|$

Comment: Added it, but there was an escaping error where the `$` had to be escaped to end the MathJax. Fixed it by changing | with \, and it worked.

Comment: Oh oops, that was a typo on my part. Yeah, backslash is correct.

Answer (score -1):

## LS, Part 2: Sebald Code [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

**WARNING:** You still not gonna answer a challenge about ponies?

---

Sebald code is a code developed by Dr. Gustav Sebald purely for communication through movies. It is decoded like this:

1. We look for an instance of "ring" case-insensitive
2. Starting from the word just after the "ring" we add this to an empty string
3. We jump 11 words and add the next word after that
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until we pass one of the words "ring"
5. The string we've been adding to is the plaintext.

Note that if the string doesn't contain "ring", just return an empty string `''`.

### Testcases (TODO)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

Answer (score -1):

## Output your Votes [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

The challenge is simple: Print to stdout the current total score (upvotes minus downvotes) of your answer.

For obvious reasons, you do not have to include the ID of your answer in the program; you may take it from stdin or specify a place in the code where the ID must be inserted.
Your program may assume that the computer it is running on has internet access and isn't restricted by SE API ratelimiting. Your program does not need to use the SE API to get the vote count, but that's probably the easiest way to do it.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

### Meta

Is this a dupe? I wouldn't be surprised if it is.

Answer (score -1):

## Help Santa Rest

Santa has finally delivered presents to everyone at the stroke of midnight in a day, and now he wants some well-deserved rest. He is just about to sit down when the present managing computer suddenly calls out: "ME NEED REST." Now he is asking you to write him a program that does... *nothing*.

You *will* be given command line args, you will be given STDIN input. You must swallow/ignore the input and after some length of time, quit the program. You may have no externally visible effects (other than RAM/CPU usage obviously), and the program must not hang.

### Testcases

`NullPointerException`

### Scoring

Santa wants to type this in as quickly as possible so he can rest, so this challenge is scored in bytes, as standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: So, what *should* the program do? Quit? Probably loads of 0-byte solutions to this.

Comment: @Adám the program should do nothing and exit. true, but 0 byters are not possible in quite a few languages (i.e. Java, golflangs that implicitly print the input, C(++)(#), Kotlin)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more fun to have to swallow all input?

Comment: @Adám isn't that what I'm describing?

Comment: Well, if the program quits immediately, it won't have a chance to swallow any input.

Comment: @Adám not quit *immediately*. i meant do nothing from an outside perspective, as in no STDOUTput or alert boxes or whatever

Comment: Then it is still unclear to me. How long should the program run and swallow input before quitting?

Comment: @Adám as long as it does not hand (i.e. enter into an infnite loop)

Answer (score -1):

## Print my Country

This challenge is simple: Your program must output the two-character country code of the computer it is currently being run on, according to the computer's locale settings. (Capitalization doesn't matter.) For example, were I to run your program on a computer with a location set to the United States, your program should output `US`. You may assume that your program is running on the latest version (Bullseye, if I'm not mistaken) of Debian Linux. This *does not need* to be accurate; I could easily set the locale to Antartica while being in Britain.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program wins!

Comment: Is this even possible? How can the computer possibly know where it is physically? And who says it even *is* in a country?

Comment: @Adám The program only needs to print the system's locale, which may or may not be accurate. I could easily set my location to Antartica while actually being in Britain. I have clarified some of the language.

Comment: Removing the restriction of system could make it more interesting. Answers should specify what system / environment they are running on.

Answer (score -1):

## Generate 3d Christmas tree using "3d pixel art"

Imagine you are building Christmas tree from 1x1x1 sized cubes that can be attached just by sharing a side. At least one input - `size`, but can be more granular (`height`, `bottom_width`, etc.).

Any kind of algorithm you like, data representation should be set of 3d int vectors containing positions of each cube.

The more natural looking, the better.

If you want to visualize it too, even better. But it's not essential (I may try to visualize some of your creations).

Answer (score -1):

## Halting detector <s>(Archived)</s>

Choose a Turing complete language and write a program in this language that, given a program in 1TB, decide whether it halts.

Your program would likely be more than 1TB, which results in transferring difficulty<sup>1</sup>. Therefore, you only need to show your construction and prove your code length.

Shortest code in each language win. A Turing complete language which write 2TB of program to do a loop would make short submission but that won't be fun (and I don't think such language exist now)

<sup>1</sup> Yeah it isn't the main point

Comment: This is literally impossible, due to the halting problem. Also how are we to submit an entire terabyte of code?

Comment: @Seggan I'm not the OP, but the problem specifies the program is less than 1 TB, so in principle you could solve it with a very large lookup table. And it says "you only need to show your code construction and prove your code length".

Comment: There are so many unsolved conjectures in mathematics that may impact the halting or non-halting of a program. For example, if you can express Collatz conjecture (specifically, an infinite loop that stops when a nontrivial Collatz loop is found) in 1TB of code in language X, you can't solve this challenge in X.

Comment: @Bubbler True, I suppose whether you can solve it depends on what counts as a solution. Like could you just say "this solution exists, but you would need to solve a lot of conjectures to actually construct it"?

Comment: @Seggan For example, you can just create a language called PythonAfter1TB which simply ignore first 1TB source and interpret following source as Python 3.10 (or do nothing and halt if your source is less than 1TB).

Comment: @tsh "but that won't be fun (and I don't think such language exist now)"

Comment: @tsh and what would that achieve? besides, it doesn't change the fact that this problem is impossible

Comment: @l4m2 I don't think there is some language (defined by implementation) support a single file with 1TB content as its source code currently.

Answer (score -1):

## Character Values Quine

Write a program that prints out a sequence of integer values corresponding to the character codes in the source code.

For example, the program:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

has a valid corresponding integer sequence of:

```
112 114 105 110 116 40 34 72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33 34 41
```

### Rules

- You may use a non-numerical sequence delimiter of your choice.
- The **order of values** in the sequence must be maintained for this challenge.
- The integers may be in **any numerical base** with a radix of 2 or larger. (binary or up). All the integers must have the same base.
- Code comments are permitted.
- The program may not read from its own source code.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest-length solution wins.

###### __

My first question, so please let me know what could/should be changed. Thanks!

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction to ASCII?

Comment: @Adám That might be unecessary, but I was mainly thinking that a mixture of unicode and ascii characters wouldn't be great. Is that a concern?

Comment: @Adám Okay, after thinking about I believe you're right in that it's rather arbitrary so I've removed it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE and thanks for using the Sandbox! You may want to think though the allowed encodings - some languages use special code pages (not Unicode nor ASCII, see [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) or [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles)). I suggest allowing them and even allowing code pages specifically crafted for this challenge (eg. program `adcbd` returning `1 2 3 4 2` with encoding `a:1 b:4 c:3 d:2`). But that's up to you.

Comment: This seems to fall under [generalized quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595/91213), a type of challenge we'd rather avoid

Comment: @mousetail I think that allowing custom encodings may result in some clever solutions that don't use the standard quine approach. I don't know however if the probability is high enough to post it against the generalized quine discouragement.

Comment: I really don't see how using a different base could ever lead to a different approach to the standard quine

Answer (score -1):

## Generate a random halting Brainfuck code

Generate a random valid halting brainfuck program using `[]+-<>`. Every halting program should be possibly outputted.

## Sandbox Notes:

- What should I add?
- Is it a duplicate?

Comment: I would add "Every halting program should be possibly outputted *with nonzero probability*." Also, I don't think there is any other viable approach than implementing [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51273/78410) and randomly quitting when a program halts, which makes your challenge a possible duplicate.

Comment: @Bubbler They can be wrapped into each other(this+loop outputting unseen entries=that,that+random output then halt=this), if these two wrappers treated non-trivial then it's not a dup

Comment: This is impossible, since you can't determine if a program halts. Should it generate a program that solves the colatz conjecture or not?

Answer (score -1):

[Sum of numbers of arbitrary length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257483/sum-numbers-which-are-string)

Comment: This seems like it would be fairly trivial in most languages. Maybe add a restriction that there shouldn't be floating point errors (e.g. in many languages, 0.2 + 0.3 = 0.30000000000000004)

Comment: @Jacob If there will be floating point errors then it will not meet the condition "summarize them as normal numbers"

Answer (score -1):

## Route Planning for a delivery driver

There is a town that consists of a single long road with evenly spaced houses. Each house either needs rice, represented with a negative number, or can provide rice, represented with a positive number.

```
[-1, 50, -1, -1, -1, -50, 3, 1]
```

Here, the first house needs one grain of rice, the second can provide 50 etc.

Your delivery truck starts at the very left edge of the town, and must end on the very right edge. It has a infinite capacity, but you can't deliver if it's empty.

The sum of the input list is guaranteed to be 0.

Given a list of requirements, output the shortest possible path that can deliver to every address.

### Test cases

| Test Case | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 5, -5 | 3 |
| -5, 5 | 5 |
| 2, -5, 3 | 6 |
| -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1 | 12 |

Answer (score -1):

## Paint you a Picture for Piet Perfection

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Make a Piet program that does whatever you want—but make it pretty.

Your goal is to paint a beautiful picture with an interesting function.

Your program may do anything, but your submission is much more likely to gain upvotes if it is interesting or related to the content of the picture. Likewise, your program could be incredibly interesting but look very ugly and thus receive few upvotes.

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the submission with the highest score wins.

---

Meta sandboxing: This might be too vague, should the program guidelines be more specific?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of popularity contest ("do whatever you want but make it pretty") is exactly the kind that we've decided [isn't a good fit for the site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25387/16766).

Comment: @DLosc Booooooo

Comment: Yeah, I understand the reasons, but I'm not entirely happy with the outcome. Tweetable Mathematical Art was one of my favorite questions. Popularity contests and what to do with them have been one of the site's most vexing questions for a lot of years. We still [discuss the issues in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/popconversation) from time to time.

Comment: Improvement idea: Create a Piet program that describes what it does in the picture itself.

Answer (score -1):

## My prefix is food, my suffix is rude

> My prefix is food.
> My suffix is rude.
> My infix comes in rounds.
> I keep you off the ground.
>
> What am I?

This is [the first "Riley riddle"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/62436), created by Riley. Riddles of this sort has become a trend in the Puzzling SE. Let us do a code-golf challenge equivalent of it.

The challenge is to write a program/function that expects the input to be one of three distinct values of your choice, and output what the code's prefix/suffix/infix of your choice would output, respectively.

To be more specific, the affixes shall have no input or have the input ignored, and have a constant output. For sake of preventing trivial solutions, their outputs shall be all different.

As for the full code, any input that matches none of the three values falls into *don't care* situation. Standard loopholes apply.

This is a code-golf, so the submission whose full code is the shortest in length wins. The lengths of the affixes won't compromise the score.

If possible, please include a poem describing what your code does, just like the original riddle! ;-)

Comment: Why the downvote tho?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm not sure I understand what the challenge means. Could you give an example program?

Answer (score -1):

## Play turn-less chess

[king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)

---

In this challenge, you'll write a chess bot...but with a twist. Your bot can move at any time, so the faster you can think, the faster you can move. You'll write code for a custom CPU (so that precise timing is possible), and try to checkmate your opponent's king.

**Rules:**

- White doesn't necessarily move first; both bots get the opportunity to start moving immediately. If both bots move in the same CPU cycle, white moves first
- If a bot tries to make an impossible move (pushing a pawn into an occupied square, castling with a moved rook, etc.), the move fails, and the bot is penalized by losing a certain amount of time (or possibly the number of cycles the opponent spent on their last move)
- Instructions will cost 1 CPU cycle, with the exception of moving, which will cost a fairly large number of cycles to make rapidly moving pieces to overwhelm smart bots less overpowered
- Bots will play each other round-robin style, both as white and black. Bots will be scored using a modified Elo system (designed such that the order in which the games are played doesn't matter)

Comment: I would strongly suggest 1 cycle per instruction, anything else will get way to complex way to quickly while adding nothing. Plus it won't actually effectively prevent ties. Instead, one bot could maybe start half a cycle earlier like in regular chess.

Comment: @mousetail I don't see how it would get "way too complex", or how it would "add nothing". It would happen all the time that two bots move at the same time. I don't want white to have an advantage, since it would cause the games to run faster and result in less draws if only one balanced game took place. As for complexity, I don't see how it adds any, and it adds a bit of strategy for people who _really_ want to optimize their bots.

Comment: You could run games with both sides starting once, then the overall winner is whoever won the fastest to eliminate ties

Comment: @mousetail Maybe, but draws still exist. And if everything is integer numbers of cycles, bots winning in the same number of cycles could also happen. And I don't see how that's less complex than what I'm doing.

Comment: I really dislike needing do do anything complex to calculate the speed of a section of code other than counting the lines. I'd need to reference the instruction set to understand the impact of every line, instead of being able to quickly tell if one snippet is faster than another

Comment: If I wanted to need a calculator to find the speed of my program I'd rather program in x86

Comment: Ties to exist, obviously if one side ties the other decides. If both games tie then they'd tie without a first move advantage also so it wouldn't make any difference

Comment: Hmm, I do see your point. I think I'm still going to make some things cost multiple cycles (moving, mainly), but I guess I'll do integers.

Comment: On a completely different note: I'd recommend making the winning condition capturing the king since keeping track of check rules in such a limited time would be near impossible

Comment: @mousetail You'd still need to do the exact same process as "keeping track of check rules" if you want to avoid your king being captured...

Comment: True, but that adds a interesting element to the game. Can you move out of check before your opponent realizes? Instead of having to wait for a long time due to a invalid move in which your opponent will probably have time to checkmate you anyways

Comment: @mousetail Ooh...what if when you're put in check, you receive some sort of interrupt, like your opponent saying "check"? And maybe making a move that would put your king in check is handled differently from just making an invalid move.

Comment: Possible, but that might make the rules too complex. Not sure how to fix it though

Answer (score -1):

## Minimum Buttons on a calculator to get from one number to another [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

My calculator looks like this:

```
·   ·   ·   ·   ·
  1   2   3   +
·   ·   ·   ·   ·
  4   5   6   -
·   ·   ·   ·   ·
  7   8   9   * 
·   ·   ·   ·   ·
  =       0   /  
·   ·   ·   ·   ·
```

Given a starting number and a ending number, calculate the minimum sequence of button presses required to get from the starting number to the ending number.

### Notes:

- `/` is integer division, no need to handle floats
- Simple calculators always calculate from left to right, no complex order of operations
- A `=` is needed at the end to display the final number if the start and ending number are different

### Test Cases

| A | B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 | `+1=` |
| 49 | 33 | `-16=` |
| 120 | 1081 | `*9+1=` |

More test cases TBD

Comment: Should there be an `=` at the end of the third test case?

Comment: Isn't `+97=` a shorter solution for the last test case?

Comment: Is `+961=` also a valid answer for the last test case?

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes.

Comment: Must first button be one of "+-*/" or what happened if I press "1" at beginning? May input already equals to output? Could you add more testcases that require using more than 1 operators in the output?

Answer (score -1):

## Infinitely spew corporate B.S.

<sup>(Throwing a touch of shade at [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content) [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389262/ai-ml-tool-examples-part-3-title-drafting-assistant) [decisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows) [made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388401/new-blog-post-from-our-ceo-prashanth-community-is-the-future-of-ai) by StackExchange over on [Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/))</sup>

If you've ever read a company's announcement blog post or press release, you've likely thought to yourself "Wow, I couldn't understand a word of that!" This is the effect of a marketing technique often referred to as "spewing corporate B.S." which, while often frustrating to read, can help you and your business dodge a lot of bullets in the P.R. department (or at least, buy yourself some time).

After recent actions made by the company you work at, you've realized that  your company doesn't have time to formulate a good response to its customers' concerns—but you know just how to deal with the problem.

In this challenge, your task is to write a program or function that, given no input (or a seed), infinitely writes randomized company-speak.

### How to write it

**SANDBOXING: TODO - spec out how this will work. I'm thinking that it will just choose random words from a word bank, but I should specify how grammar can work, or maybe it would make sense for the word list to be taken as input (leaning towards this)f? Please comment any suggestions.**

Here are some example corporate sentences your program may write, according to the above criteria:

> We are revisiting a broader approach to improving the user-experience of  our new experiment concerning recent concern.
>
> We are excited to share a more holistic initiative to produce positive results from our new experiment.
>
> We are committed to hearing your feedback in a more positive exploration of the product.

### Rules

- Your submission can be a full- program or a function
- You may return a generator that can generate sentences infinitely rather than printing.
- Your “randomness” doesn’t have to be evenly distributed, but there must be a non-zero chance that any possible sentence might be outputted by your submission.
- **SANDBOXING: more rules**

Comment: +1 for humor but needs to be a lot better specified. You need a objective scoring critereum at least

Comment: @mousetail Sorry, it’s code-golf, forgot to mention. I don’t have time to update it yet but will do so in a few hours. It’s definitely not specified enough, since I’m still not entirely sure how the challenge will work—just wanted to post it so I A) don’t forget it, and B) can get some initial feedback on the idea

Comment: How are you going to check if a answer is sufficiently corporate or sufficiently B.S.?

Comment: Just make sure none of the SE staff notice…

Comment: Is the output allowed to be a sentence that doesn't make sense?

Answer (score -1):

## Detect sloppy randomness

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

The C `rand()` function is often implemented like so:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;

int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

However this is not a very good rng and definitely not a cryptographically secure one. Your task is to write code that detects this rng.

Specifically your code takes as input a sequence of 100 (or fewer if you so wish) numbers between 0 and 32767 inclusive.

For a random input the code should output "random" with at least 99.9999% probability and "not random" with at most 0.0001% probability (one in a million).

However if the input is generated using (successive calls to) rand then your code must output "not random" always.

Also, your code must be fast. Specifically it should run in under a second. Output as per standard [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules.

## Meta

Should I use a 64-bit rng? Solutions in fast languages can probably just brute force the 31-bit state. This would also allow to relax the time requirements.

Comment: Under a second on what hardware?

Answer (score -1):

[Inspired](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262588/), maybe copy background from there

Given a map, output a shortest possible input.

Test cases:

```
Start here _ /  => / \
             \

               /
              /
Start here _ /\/ => /// /\/ \/\
             \/\

                /
               /
              /\
Start here _ /\/\ => //// //\\ /\/ \/\/
             \/\/

                   /\/
                /\/\/
Start here _ /\/\/\/\/ => /\//\//\/ \/\//\// /\/\/\/\/ \\\
             \/\/\  /\    \/\/\\//\
              \   \/
               \
```

Comment: What do you mean by shortest? Smallest number of paths? Do the paths also need to be shortest possible? (in your last example first or second path can skip the last `/` and the third I think is simply wrong (: )

Comment: @pajonk Sum new path, ` \ ` and `/`. Don't see problem on Test Case 3 or 4

Comment: In the last test case, third path, you have `/\/\\//\/` but the 6th segment (first of two `/`s) doesn't exist in the map (or I don't understand something).

Comment: @pajonk Misread as 3rd test case.

Comment: It is unclear what the challenge is.

Answer (score -1):

## Python: `*args` or `**kwargs`?

Is it a regular argument or a keyword argument?

---

In Python, there are two types of specifying arguments to a function:

Regular argument (`arg`): `f("regular argument")`

Keyword argument (`kwarg`): `f(keywordarg="keyword argument")`

Keyword arguments in Python always are in the form of variable assignments and regular arguments are anything else. [If you want to learn more about `*args` and `**kwargs`, click here.](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

---

### Task

Given an input **string** consisting of only ascii characters that is a valid argument (regular or keyword), you must output one of two constant, distinct values representing whether it is an `arg` or a `kwarg`. Shortest code wins!

---

### Test cases

```
3              -> arg
num = 3        -> kwarg
num=3          -> kwarg
a=b            -> kwarg
a==b           -> arg
False          -> arg
"kwarg"        -> arg
arg="arg"      -> kwarg
"kwarg=kwarg"  -> arg
a=b==c         -> kwarg
b==c           -> arg
[1,2,3,4]      -> arg
dict={1:2,3:4} -> kwarg
[1,2][i:=0]    -> arg

"""more than
one line!"""   -> arg

mstring='''
indeed more
than one line
'''            -> kwarg
```

---

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

---

### Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this too focused on Python?
- Do I need more test cases?
- Any other feedback?

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Comment: Can we assume ASCII only?

Comment: @mousetail why are you asking?

Comment: This question is just "does this string start with a valid python identifier followed by a =". But what constituted a valid identifier in python for weired unicode edge cases gets extremely complex. If you want unicode support you need a very large number of unicode test cases.

Comment: @mousetail sure I’ll allow ascii only (but maybe a bonus for non-ascii as well?)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/91213

Comment: @mousetail no bonus it is.

Comment: @mousetail and about the valid identifier part: I said only valid arguments, so you won’t get `£=1` or `class`.

Comment: What if you get some weird Unicode character that normalizes to `=`?

Comment: @mousetail i only allowed ascii

Comment: `£` is not ASCII

Comment: @mousetail wait WHAT!?!

Comment: @mousetail should we move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147210/discussion-between-i-am-kind-of-a-language-dev-and-mousetail).

Comment: Suggested test case `[1,2][i:=0]` is args

Comment: @mousetail that's quite intresting!

Comment: @mousetail added

Answer (score -1):

## Decimal to fraction

In the pool of questions on CGCC, I have not found a question with this task.

---

Given a float in base 10, output a fraction in simplified form, improper or mixed. The output format can be any reasonable one. In [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins!

### Test cases

```
3.5 -> 7/2 or 3 1/2
0.25 -> 1/4 or 0 1/4
```

---

### Meta

- Did I miss a duplicate?
- Any more test cases?
- Anything else?

Comment: [Pretty much a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17239/114446)

Answer (score -1):

## Catouterr

A cat that writes to two streams? I’m in!

---

Write a full program with these properties:

- If the input string ends in `outerr`, remove that part and write the rest to `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.
- If the input string ends in `err` but not `outerr`, remove that part and write the rest to `STDERR` only.
- If the input string ends in `out`, remove that part and print the rest to `STDOUT`.
- Otherwise, print it to `STDOUT` unchanged.

`STDOUT` and `STDERR` can be replaced by a reasonable alternative. Also, `STDERR` is not ignored. However, insuppressible messages are ignored.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

---

## Meta

- Ask away!

Comment: Does it have to be a program or are functions allowed?

Comment: I assume when you say "remove that part and write it" you mean "remove that part and write the rest to"?

Comment: @CommandMaster full programs only. Added.

Comment: @noodleman yes. Fixed.

Comment: What would be examples of "reasonable alternatives" for stdout and stderr? Would it be reasonable to output both to stdout, but with a separator?

Answer (score -1):

## Optimal Span for Multiple Byte Ranges [Draft]

I recently ran into the following challenge, you have a list of common crawl URL indexes that have the setup below. Each of the GZ files are ~1.2GB, the challenge would be to design the most efficient solution that can respond with the decrypted byte span. If this if of interest, I'll revise this to flush out more details.

In the real world, some considerations are:

1. Cache vs HTTP fetch byte range
2. Minimizing number of requests by making requests spanning multiple offsets
3. Decrypting entire file for multiple offsets vs decrypting offsets individually
4. Trade off between # of connections, download time, local storage space, decryption time

Example:

| FileName.gz | Offset | Length | CONTENT_DIGEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2023-23/segments/1685224648465.70/warc/CC-MAIN-20230602072202-20230602102202-00011.warc.gz | 755688583 | 1327 | 123456789 |
| crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2023-23/segments/1685224648465.70/warc/CC-MAIN-20230602072202-20230602102202-00011.warc.gz | 86276364 | 3404 | ABCDEFGHI |
| crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2023-23/segments/1685224648465.70/warc/CC-MAIN-20230602072202-20230602102202-00011.warc.gz | 963176585 | 1294 | 987654321 |

Answer (score -1):

## Write a check

Given the check (cheque, for non-Americans) number, payee, amount, and memo as input, print or return a check in this format:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| John and Jane Doe                                                      ***** |
| 123 Pine St.                                                                 |
| Anytown, USA 12345                                Date: ____________________ |
|                                                                              |
| Pay to the                                                                   |
|   order of _____________________________________________________ $__________ |
|                                                                              |
| ________________________________________________________________ DOLLARS     |
|                                                                              |
| First Bank of Code Golf - Anytown, USA                                       |
|                                                                              |
| For ________________________________  AUTHORIZED-SIGNATURE-JOHN-AND-JANE-DOE |
|                                                                              |
| [314159265[  2718281828/  *****                                              | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Parts marked with underscores are for the account holder to fill out, while parts with asterisks are printed on the check.

1. Fill out the check number in the top-right corner, left-padded with spaces. Check 101 has   `101` in place of the asterisks.
2. Fill out the check number on the bottom, left-padded with zeros. Check 101 has `00101`.
3. Anywhere the user writes, leave one underscore before the user's writing and as many afterwards as necessary to fill the space. You may assume your program will not be given input that will overflow any of the fields.
4. Write the current date in the format `November 2, 2023` (`%B %-d, %Y`).
5. Write the numerical amount in the format `1,234.56`. The comma is required for amounts greater than or equal to $1,000.
6. Write out the amount in the format "One thousand two hundred thirty-four and 56/100". Pad the rest of the field for it with hyphens (`-`), except one underscore at the end.

Here is an example of check #9876 written on September 30, 2023, paying $1,234.56 to `Acme Inc.` for a `Widget purchase`:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| John and Jane Doe                                                       9876 |
| 123 Pine St.                                                                 |
| Anytown, USA 12345                                Date: _September 30, 2023_ |                
|                                                                              |
| Pay to the                                                                   |
|   order of _Acme Inc.___________________________________________ $_1,234.56_ |        
|                                                                              |
| _One thousand two hundred thirty-four and 56/100---------------_ DOLLARS     |                           
|                                                                              |
| First Bank of Code Golf - Anytown, USA                                       |
|                                                                              |
| For _Widget purchase________________  AUTHORIZED-SIGNATURE-JOHN-AND-JANE-DOE |             
|                                                                              |
| [314159265[  2718281828/  09876                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Standard loopholes are prohibited. You may write a function or a complete program, and you may output the check to stdout or return it either as a newline-delimited string or as a list of strings. A trailing newline is optional.

Comment: Is the check itself part of the input or also generated by the code?

Comment: @Philippos the check is generated.

Comment: Then maybe there is too much stuff that cannot really be golfed.

Comment: @Philippos do you think making it an input would be an improvement?

Comment: "Fill out the check number in the top-left corner" You mean top right?

Comment: Also, what's the maximum amount we have to handle? Can the limit be $999,999.99 or does it have to handle millions?

Comment: @Bbrk24 oops, yes, top right. And it is limited to $9,999.99, because any more would overflow the numeric amount field.

Answer (score -1):

## All good regex come in threes

We've had challenges about [two regex matching each other but not themselves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22648/72726) and [a complicated relationship of five regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/129941/72726), but don't they say that all good things come in threes?

- Write a chain of three regex, each one matching the next, but neither itself not the previous one
- Thus, of our three regex, RE1 will only match RE2, RE2 will only match RE3 and RE3 will only match RE1
- Don't ask about slashes. We are talking about regular expressions, not slashes. Even if some languages use slashes as one way to delimit regular expressions, the slashes are not part of the regular expressions, so they are not part of the challenge
- If you use an extension to the POSIX regex standard, define our dialect and compete in that dialect league. Champions league is pure POSIX basic regular expressions
- This is regex golf, so the shortest sum of the three lengths wins

Answer (score -1):

## Vim (not) Golf

Starting vim with `--clean`; what is the longest English sentence you can type without leaving normal mode?

---

Should a clause be added for `/` not being a valid key?

Answer (score -1):

### Fast group action

For the purposes of this challenge permutation is a bijective function on the natural numbers.

Cycles are a particular kind of permutation, which we can represent as lists of integers enclosed in a set of parentheses. If a number appears in the list then the result of the permutation is the next value of the list, or in the case of the last value the first in the list. If the number does not appear, its result is itself.

So for example (1 2 4) maps 1 to 2, 2 to 4, 4 to 1 and every other natural number to itself.

We can compose two permutations to get a new permutation. In the notation we compose two cycles by placing them next to each other, the result is that the right permutation is applied first followed by the left one.

So (3 2)(1 2 4) maps 1 to 3, 2 to 4, 3 to 2 and 4 to 1. Everything else maps to itself. This can be written more simply as a single cycle (1 3 2 4). Not every permutation written this way can be simplified. For example (1 2)(9 8) cannot be written as a single cycle since the two cycles being composed do not contain any common numbers. However cycles that are disjoint like this do commute, so this is equivalent to (9 8)(1 2).

While not every permutation can be written as a cycle, every permutation can be written as the composition of cycles. So the above notation is enough to represent permutations.

However as we have seen there is a degree of ambiguity here. Permutations can be written multiple ways, so we will define a normal form which gives every permutation a single representation.

To be normal a representation must satisfy the following qualities:

- No number appears in more than one cycle.
- The first number in each cycle must be the largest in the cycle.
- Cycles whose first number is smaller should appear earlier.

Here are a few examples rewritten in normal form:

```
(1 2 4) -> (4 1 2)
(3 2)(1 2 4) -> (4 1 3 2)
(1 2)(9 8) -> (2 1)(9 8)
(1 4 7)(2 3) -> (3 2)(7 1 4)
```

### Task

In this challenge you will take as input two finite permutations (a finite number of cycles each of finite length) in normal form and output the composition of those two permutations also in normal form.

You may take input as a list of lists or any suitable list-like structure. You may exclude or include 0 from the natural numbers.

The goal is to minimize Big-O asymptotic time complexity in terms of the number of bits in the input.

### Sandbox

I wrote this up because I needed to implement this for work I was doing, and had fun. This seems like the sort of thing that would have existing fast algorithms, but when researching for my work and again when writing this I wasn't able to find any.

If this is a well known problem, I don't think it's worth asking a fastest code about it.  I'd probably modify it to be [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) and [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). So if anyone knows of an algorithm in the literature, let me know.

Comment: I might be missing something, but couldn't you normalize the values in the cycles, so they are at most \$O(n)\$ (this step actually isn't trivial, but it's possible in deterministic linear time), compose the permutations in \$O(n)\$ time, partition it back to cycles in \$O(n)\$, and then undo the normalization?

Comment: Just as to the title, I don't believe 'group action' is the best way to describe this, especially since you do not directly reference groups or group actions in the post. While yes it is a group action (of \$\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})\$ on \$\mathbb{N}\$), it may just be best to focus on fast composition of permutations.

Comment: @CommandMaster If elements are widely spreaded but only a few different elements, then the complexity would fall on map (besides fast scanning, there's a step of sorting)

Answer (score -1):



Answer (score -2):

### Underhand Bejewled

Help me to write a game of bejewled, which cannot be lost!

### Bejewled game rules

If you ever played bejewled, you can skip this, but for those who did not see it ever:

- Playing field of 8*8 grid is filled in with gems of 7 different types randomly
- By swapping two adjective stones, your goal is to create a line of at least three same type of stones in the either vertical or horizontal line
- If did so, the gems will dissappear, points are added (say 20 points for a matching) and new gems are provided randomly from the top
- image related:

[image]

### Your challenge

Provide me a game which cannot be lost. In other words, the gems falling from the top are not random at all, but are falling in order that there is always at least one possibility to match three gems

**But**, from looking at the code at level of newbie programmer, it should look like that game acts as if it was random

### Output

Playable game. As long as it is the grid of 8*8 filled in with 7 different types of "gems" the game is ok. It does not to have killer graphics, neither it does not need to be playable by mouse. (But in that case please make sure you show which "gem" is hovered and then selected)

### Winning criteria

This is popularity contest. So highest rated game wins

Comment: I think this is too big a task to work well for an underhanded contest. The programs will be way too large for anyone to actually read the source and try to find what's underhanded about it.

Comment: Thats what I was also afraid of. I will either take it as lesson to progress on my programming skill, or abandon the idea completly

Answer (score -2):

### Progress 100%

I am building a download manager and I need to show a progress of all my files been downloaded.

For that I created an event mechanism that reports on the progress of each individual file. It sends me the information on how many bytes `B` have been downloaded of file `T` total.

Please help me show the average progress of all the files.

### Input

Integer C between 1 to 100, followed by new line, followed by C progresses separated by new line. Each progress is constructed of two numbers with the maximum size of 64 bits: `B` `T`, separated by space.

**Input options**

The input is a String available from the following options

- file
- stdin
- method parameter

### Output

Floating number between 0 to 1, the average of all the progresses. It must be displayed to 11 decimal places, floored.

### Criterial

Shortest code wins

### Example

**Input file:**

```
3
5 10
1024 1024
20 100
```

**Output**

```
0.56666666666
```

**Explanation**

```
((5/10) + (1024/1024) + (20/100)) / 3 = 17/30
```

### Example2

**Input file:**

```
1
2 10
```

**Output**

```
0.2
```

### Example3

```
2  
Long.MAX_VALUE Long.MAX_VALUE  
5 10
```

**Explanation**
In this example Long.MAX_VALUE represent the maximum 64 bit value, so if you use 64 bit value for storing the sum of the averages it will not work in this case.

**Output**

```
0.66666666666
```

Comment: 1. It's not clear from your specification how the result should be computed. The "total progress" implies to me that I should figure out how many bytes have been downloaded of the total, i.e. `sum(B)/sum(T)`. However, your first example suggests, that we should actually compute the arithmetic mean/average of the individual progresses. If so, please state this clearly. 2. By requiring 11 digits of accuracy, you require 64-bit floats (double precision), because 32-bit floats only have 7.something decimal digits. Is this intentional? (seeing your input is only 32 bits)

Comment: @MartinBüttner how about now? I do want the high precision

Comment: My first point still stands. It's not clear from the specification how the result should be computed.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I expect you to process all the progresses and find the average one, not sure how to say it right.

Comment: Just like that, but as far as I can see your challenge currently doesn't mention "average" or "arithmetic mean" anywhere.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Anything else?

Comment: Why did you remove it again? And what's the purpose of the hint?

Comment: @MartinBüttner sorry had 2 windows opened. The hint helps you to understand that you cannot store the sum of all the progresses in 64 bit value.

Comment: What does "*up to 11 digits of accuracy mean*"? That I can supply only 3 digits, but I may not supply 12? And what counts as a "digit of accuracy", anyway: are you talking decimal places or significant figures? And if significant figures, what is the correct output if the average progress is exactly 0?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I want an 11 digits after the dot of accuracy in the output. So 3/10 will produce 0.33333333333 and 0/10 will produce 0. Maybe you can suggest a better way of writing it down.

Comment: I've edited in some changes. I would suggest also deleting the hint and replacing it with a *test case*. It would also be good to describe a test case (it will probably be too long to post) which demonstrates that it's not sufficient to use IEEE754 double-precision.

Comment: @PeterTaylor is it ready now?

Comment: *It would also be good to describe a test case (it will probably be too long to post) which demonstrates that it's not sufficient to use IEEE754 double-precision*.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't understand what you are saying, can you please explain it a little bit more

Comment: Since you're requiring programs to support averaging 2^31 numbers and you want output to a precision of about 35 bits, a naïve solution with 64-bit floating point will be incorrect, but that might not be obvious to everyone who would attempt an answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor but the output is between 0-1 so 64-bit value should do

Comment: 31 + 35 = 66, which is rather more than the 53 bits of mantissa in a 64-bit float.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22532/discussion-between-ilya-gazman-and-peter-taylor).

Answer (score -2):

## Create a Drawing Guide for a Polygram

Poor old Jim, he's just terrible at drawing [polygrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygram_(geometry)), and he's asked you to create a "drawing guide" for him - an ascii polygram with numbered edges, so he can follow the instructions.

### Challenge

Write a program to produce an ascii polygram with `P <= 10`; each edge of the polygram should be made of a single digit 0-9, showing the order in which the edges should be drawn.

### Input

Your program should receive (via STDIN, as function arguments, or some other language-appropriate method): `P`, the number of edges/vertices of the polygram, and `Q`, the spacing. In the notation as per the Wikipedia link, you'll be drawing a `{p/q}` polygram.

### Output

Either print to STDOUT or return (or something else language-appropriate) a multiline string showing the drawing guide for the given polygram. The string can be any size you like, as long as it's large enough to display a clear polygram.

### Notes

Your code should be able to handle compound regular polygons as well as regular regular polygons, and also inputs of q > p/2 (poor old Jim doesn't realize that the polygram for `{p/q}` is the same as for `{p/p-q}`).

### Example Output for {10,3}

```
              5              
             5 4             
                4            
     21     5        888     
     2 11115     8888  7     
     2    5111888 4    7     
     2     888111  4   7     
     2  888      111   7     
     8885           4117     
  8882               4 711   
 8   2 5               7  111
     25               47     
 9   5                 7    0
  9  2                 74  0 
    52                 7  0  
   9 2                 7 4   
  5 92                 7 04  
     9                 70  4 
 5   2                 7     
5    29                7    4
6666 2 9              07   33
    666              0 7333  
     2 696           337     
     2   9666     333  7     
     2    9  66633 0   7     
     2      333 666    7     
     2   339       666 7     
     2333   9    0    67     
             9  0            
               0
```

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest in bytes wins. Tiebreaker goes to the most votes.

Comment: I have a python solution to this which is ~600 bytes, so it's definitely doable, and it's not easy...

Comment: I think the spec needs to be more prescriptive for this to make a good question, especially since the example seems to indicate that you're not currently even prohibiting the lines from having gaps. At a minimum I would say that you should require the lines to be equivalent to those produced by Bresenham's algorithm, and specify how overlaps should be handled; at the extreme, you could tie it down so tightly that it becomes a parameterised [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Answer (score -2):

## Pointer to pointers to pointers to pointers

You should choose a language supporting pointers like C. And your task is simple: demonstrate a legitimate use of the most level of pointers.

You should justify your code by describing an algorithm that:

- Has only plain text, number or an array of those as input and output.
- You think it will make things easier to write those code as a part of the implementation of this algorithm.
- This implementation would have optimum memory usage (only declared variables and parameters, explicitly allocated space, and the return addresses for recursive functions count).

Other rules:

- They must be pointers to pointers directly, i.e. a pointer to an object containing a pointer doesn't count. It's better if nobody using this code will want to extend some pointer to an object later.
- Each pointer must have a different type (if your language can somehow make them the same type).
- You should create at least one pointer, and either dereference or compare two non-null pointers once in each level.
- Using pointers as arrays is only half as interesting.
- Iterators, etc, are considered in essence pointers and allowed in this challenge. But you can't define new types implementing iterators for this purpose.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: Could you specify "legitimate"? This sounds a bit like code bowling (and seems to have the same issues). With enough imagination I'm sure I can justify any depth of pointers.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Edited but, basically, it is subjective.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Added a restriction to have optimum memory usage. I'm not sure whether it works.

Answer (score -2):

## Winning Tic-Tac-Toe lines

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

For a given tic-tac-toe board of size `N**D` (for example, a normal tic-tac-toe game is `3**2`), the number of winning lines of length N is given by the expression:

$$
2^{D-1} + \sum_{S=1}^{D-1}2^{S-1}DN^{D-S}
$$

(Basically, you are summing the number of lines in each S-dimensional slice of the board.)

## The challenge:

Given N and D, your answer should output a list of D-dimensional coordinates for each winning line. Input and output are any reasonable format. You can assume that both N and D are positive integers, with N > 1. (Degenerate cases of N=1, D>1 not included.)

Since this is [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), fastest answer wins. Please explain your algorithm!

Comment: How do you intend to determine which of two answers is fastest?

Comment: yes, @randomra made the same point on chat. i'll edit this in, but i guess... i'll put together some test cases and then time them? i dunno, i was going back and forth between this and code-golf, but i'd prefer interesting and readable algorithms.

Comment: i posted this here because i really want the answer, and i hate coming up with brute force solutions... :D

Comment: Um. Given that you're asking people to enumerate an exponentially large set, in what sense will the answers not be brute force?

Comment: well, there's brute force and then there's brute force. but really it's because i don't want to do it myself, haha.

Comment: also, making use of symmetry can severely reduce the computation.

Comment: I imagine that the runtime in any such algorithm will be basically proportional to the number of things you print, so there won't be any good way to improve by algorithm and the speed will be very platform-dependent.

Answer (score -2):

## Ayn Random number generator

---

Inspired by xkcd 1277:

[image]

Write a random number generator that takes no input and generates a random integer between 1 and 100. When run less than 200 times, the frequency of all numbers needs to be between 0 and 2, but when it's ran 50 000 times, the number 42 (obviously) should have a frequence that's more than 4 standard deviations higher than the mean.

Format is code-golf. Your score is the bytecount of your code.

Comment: 1. I think it's difficult to decide objectively whether a PRNG *appears to be fair at first sight*. 2. The term *more often* should probably be quantified.

Comment: I see lots of C rand()%1000 and the like incoming...

Comment: @Ypnypn I have changed the criteria to have much lower numbers so they're easier to verify.

Comment: @Dennis I have rewritten the question to clarify what "being fair" is and what "more often" actually entails.

Comment: 1. Are you thinking of a standalone program that you run multiple times or a function that is allowed to keep a state? In the first case, not even a perfect RNG will, with overwhelming probability, satisfy the first condition. 2. Do you mean the mean and standard deviation of a perfect, uniform RNG or the one the code implements?

Comment: @Dennis I'm thinking of just a function `AynRandom()` that gets called. The frequency of numbers with a small number of iterations is subject to change, maybe from 0 to 4. The mean and Standard Deviation must be the one the code implements.

Comment: between 0 and 2 ? so `print 42` would be a valid program ?

Comment: @Falco No, because 42 would appear more than 2 times (unless you only run it twice). The problem is that I need a way to indicate that the RNG is fair with a low iteration count, but unfair with higher iteration counts. The only way I can make it work is by stating that with low iteration counts, all numbers should appear about equally often, which is either 0, 1 or 2 times.

Answer (score -2):

Please nitpick this. If there's anything that wouldn't work or would be inconvenient, however small of an issue it is, tell me about it!
Also, suggestions for *[adjective]* are more than welcome.

---

## Determine how *[adjective]* a number is ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf))

A number would be considered *[adjective*] if 0 is the result of multiplying its digits together, then multiplying the digits of the resulting number, then repeating until a single-digit number is produced. The more steps it takes to reach 0, the more *[adjective]* the number is; if the resulting number is not 0, though, the number is not *[adjective]* regardless of how long it took to finish.
The formula used to determine *[adjective]*-ness is `10-10/T` where T is however many numbers it took to reach 0 (including 0 and the initial input)

Your goal is, as the title says, to write a program or function that determines how *[adjective]* a number is, and prints every iteration along the way. Here are some **example inputs/ouputs:**

```
in: 879
out: 879    <-       (T=1)
     504    <- 8*7*9 (T=2)
     0      <- 5*0*4 (T=3)
            <- optional newline
     6.6... <- 10-10/3 (repeating decimals can be expressed in any way you want)

in: 2468
out: 2468   <-  T=1
     96     <- (T=2) 2*4*6*8
     54     <- (T=3) 9*6
     20     <- (T=4) 5*4
     0      <- (T=5) 2*0

     8      <- 10-10/5

in: -888
out: -888  
     -512   <- -8*-8*-8
     -10    <- -5*-1*-2
     0      <- -1*0

     6.6... <- 10-10/3

in: 1344
out: 1344
     48
     32
     6

     0    <- did not produce 0, so the prog/func returns 0
```

Your program must follow these **rules:**

-Takes input from STDIN.
-Throws an "error" (printed to STDOUT) and halts immediately after input if the input has one or more 0s in it *or* if it's less than three digits in length. The error must be a string, and as it's supposed to be printed to stdout, cannot be one generated by the language itself (eg `1/int(min(input()))` to check if it's zero). Lastly, the error message has to clearly define what the error is; `ERR:0` and `ERR:LEN`, for example, would suffice.

**Bonuses/Penalties:**

**-25** if it properly handles decimals. For instance, an input of 99.22 would first turn into `9*9 + 0.(2*2)`, or `9*9 + 0.4`, and so on.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the **shortest answer in bytes** wins.

Comment: I don't like the +15 penalty. Whether strings are used is vague in some languages. The constant amount +15 is too little deterrent for some languages but huge for very concise ones. The fact that you've found a short solution you don't like is sign you should rethink the problem, not try to plug the hole.

Comment: @xnor that's reasonable. I suppose it is a valid way of doing it, anyway, so I removed all mention of strings in that section. Should I also inc/decrease the bonus for decimals?

Comment: The programming languages I know either don't allow throwing user-defined errors or print them to STDERR. Now, if you just want us to print a message and exit immediately...

Comment: `...and should be printed to STDOUT.` I had a feeling that wasn't clear; I edited it, is it better now?

Comment: It's the word *throw* that throws me off (no pun intended). To [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an error usually means something rather specific. *Print an error message to STDOUT (or closest alternative)* would be less confusing in my opinion. Also, since this is code golf, I think you should require specific error messages. There's no fun in losing a contest because you chose `ERR:LEN` and somebody else got away with `EL`.

Comment: Remove bonuses altogether. It's in the [list of things to avoid](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/34718).

Comment: The error if the input contains a zero seems like a separate challenge. It may be better received if there is only one challenge. There is community support for avoiding [Chameleon challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20283).

Answer (score -2):

## Wrong tool for the task

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

#### Task

Write two full programs in the same programming language that solve the following two tasks:

1. Read two positive integers from STDIN and print their sum to STDOUT.
2. Read two positive integers from STDIN and print their product to STDOUT.

Additional details:

- Given enough time and memory, your programs has to support arbitrarily large integers.
- All integers (input and output) use standard decimal notation, have no leading zeroes and are followed by a single linefeed.

#### Scoring

The first task is code golf, so your objective is to make your program as *short* as possible.

The second task is code bowling, so your objective is to make your program as *long* as possible.

Your score is defined as follows:

[image: score formula]

The highest score wins!

#### Robbing a language

There's a catch! Only the submission with the *shortest* program in a particular language will be considered valid for task 2, so there can only be one valid answer per language.

This means that you cannot deliberately write a huge program for task 2; you actually have to pick the "wrong tool" for the task.

Additional details:

- Task 1 exists merely to provide the proper denominator for the score (and robbers have no moral anyway), so byte-per-byte copies of somebody's program for task 1 are allowed.
- If two answers use the same language and have programs of the same length for task 2, the answer that achieved that length first will be considered valid.
- If somebody invalidated your answer, you may attempt to golf your answer
  to revalidate yours and invalidate his.

Comment: I suspect this will come down to people writing code in unary and disagreeing on what input/outputs formats are valid for such a language.

Comment: @xnor I'm not sure I understood your comment. The format for I/O is purposedly restrictive, so an answer's validity should be clear-cut.

Comment: @feersum I think the log scoring does benefits unary. Say (making up numbers) task 1 takes 100 chars of BF and task2 takes 150 chars. Then, those are translated to 300 chars and 450 chars of binary, and so 2^(300) and 2^(450) chars of unary, giving a score of 1.5. In comparison, if the tasks take 20 chars and 50 chars in another language, that's about a score of 1.3. I guess this is surmountable though (20 and 100 gives 1.5).

Comment: Are the inputs decimal numbers? For a language like BF, can the numbers be taken as byte values rather than characters? What separator should be used between the numbers? Are leading zeroes OK in the output? I think you'll have to be pedantic and precise about everything given how much of the character count may depend on details, but it's doable.

Comment: Yeah that's right, it is only for Unary.

Comment: @xnor *All integers (input and output) use standard decimal notation, have no leading zeroes and are followed by a single linefeed.*

Comment: @Dennis Wow, you anticipated everything and I missed it. I take it then that input must be as a string of numerical characters? Also, do I understand right that you have to print a newline for output (say, `print a+b,"\n"` in Python)?.

Comment: @xnor Yes to both. The newline is required and you have to use numerical characters. I'd specify the exact character range, but I don't want to exclude non-ASCII languages.I'll think of a way to make it clearer.

Answer (score -2):

## GitHub Gist command-line client

Create a command-line tool that publishes a list of files as one public GitHub Gist.

### Specification

The following bullet points describe the behavior of the program. If a bullet point has "*must*", you must implement that point. If a bullet point has "*can optionally*" or "*should optionally*" you can implement that point on your own volition.

1. It *must* be a complete command-line program.
2. It *must* use the GitHub [Gists API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/).
3. It *must* post an anonymous Gist (that is, not as a GitHub user).
4. Gisted files *must* use the filename provided on the command-line.
5. The command-line *must* accept multiple positional arguments.
6. If no arguments are specified, it *must* print this usage to `STDOUT`: `gist: usage: <file> [file...]` verbatim then exit with code 0.
7. If something else goes wrong, it *must* print this message to `STDERR`: `gist: unable to gist =(` verbatim then exit with code 1.
8. If everything is successful it *must* print the Gist's HTML URL to `STDOUT`.
9. It *can optionally* accept a flag for description `-d <description`. **`floor(score * .9)`**
10. It *can optionally* accept a flag for private gisting `-p`. **`floor(score * .9)`**
11. In the case that a description flag is not used or implemented it *must* set the description to an empty string.

### Example Input/Output

The number before the prompt is the exit code of the previous command.

```
0 $ gist
gist: usage: <file> [file...]
0 $ gist no-such-file.txt
gist: unable to gist =(
1 $ gist hello.txt
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e645596ce7bceeb1ec9
0 $
```

### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins. As stated above, the following multipliers are in effect:

- (9): `score = floor(score * .9)`
- (10): `score = floor(score * .9)`
- Both (9) & (10): `score = floor(floor(score * .9) *.9)`

Comment: What's up with the Example Input/Output code snippet? The editor's preview displays it correctly.

Comment: For the usage, should those literal strings be used regardless of the name and invocation of the program, or should it substitute the correct invocation for the leading `gist`? I'm thinking particularly of cases like Java, which doesn't support hashbangs.

Comment: Literal string, I think.

Comment: That's a good point about Java. I think I'll remove the item about shebangs since it's unfair.

Comment: If both bonuses are done, is it `floor(score * .9 * .9)`, or `floor(floor(score * .9) * .9)`?

Comment: Also, if the bonuses are done, do we have to make the usage string reflect that, or just print it verbatim?

Comment: Output strings verbatim. And `floor(floor(score * .9) * .9)` for both. I'll update the question momentarily.

Comment: I'm curious why this challenge is being downvoted.

Answer (score -2):

## Golf these arrays

Your task is to output these 128 arrays: http://pastebin.com/UeBMJfv7

Gzip base64: (too long, will be added if I'll post this question).

### Rules

- You don't have to output them all. And you can output the arrays in any order. But the order of items in the arrays must be kept as is.
- You can print other arrays, which wouldn't be counted towards your score. The number of arrays you print must be no more than 10,000, and the total number of arrays, subarrays and numbers must be no more than 10,000,000.
- You can use any convenient format to represent the arrays (and the list of outputted arrays).

### Scoring

If your program or function has *n* bytes, and it printed *k* distinct arrays from the above list, your score would be *n**(128/*k*)<sup>2</sup>. Lowest score wins.

---

#### Problems

It looks too boring.

Comment: It also looks too broad.

Answer (score -2):

### The Perfect Keyboard

Back in the 1970s, keyboard designers respected the needs of programmers and languages. For example, see the IBM 2741 keyboard, designed for APL (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))):
[image]

Today, sadly, most code golfers are forced to struggle with standard keyboards, which are badly suited to the needs of their language. This has to change!

### The challenge

1. Choose a programming language.
2. Design a keyboard, which would best suit the needs of a developer (or specifically a code golfer) in said language.
3. Post the keyboard layout as an answer.
4. Explain how your keyboard enhances the programming experience.
5. Start counting votes for 7 days, until I acceopt the winning answer (the answer with most votes).
6. Optional - if you are the winner, start a [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/) project to build the thing.

### Expected Answers

This section is, of course, for the sandbox only.

I don't really expect a keyboard design which would actually improve functionality of programs in an actual serious language. I'd expect fun answers, where the keyboard design highlights soemthing fun/interesting/absurd about the language. But my expectations don't matter so much, because it's not me rating the answers, but the other users.

Example (not very good ones):

1. A Brainfuck keyboard with only 4 keys.
2. A Lisp keyboard where half the keys are parentheses.
3. A Piet keyboard - I'm sure someone will come up with something nice.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: I'm note sure if it's a valid challenge since there is no programming actually involved in answering this

Comment: @Fatalize, You're right, but it is a programming-related challenge. It requires knowledge of programming languages and people may find it interesting or amusing. I may be pushing the boundaries, I don't know.

Comment: I would personally be ok with that challenge but I don't know if other, more prominent users would find this challenge off-topic.

Comment: Judging from [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/the-line-between-art-and-programming) Meta post, there seems to be a fairly clear consensus that a question must involve programming to be on topic, not merely be programming related. So this question is fairly clearly not valid.

Comment: You could always include programming the driver or some kind of special interface for the keyboard

Comment: @BetaDecay, This challenge is about crazy creative answers. Requiring a driver implementation seems to me like a way to kill this creativity.

Comment: @isaacg, [trichoplax writes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1948/3544) "I judge it by whether the answers to it demonstrate skill and determination, or just aesthetic style" - I think a good answer to this challenge requires undestdanding a language and designing something that relates to its properties. Does it qualify as "skill and determination"? I can't say I'm sure.

Comment: The art/programming debate was specifically about popcon questions where the answers were programs. There's no doubt whatsoever that a popcon where the answers are just images would be an art question rather than a programming question. On the same basis, this is not a programming question, and does not belong on this site.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - I don't think it's an art question. The challenge isn't to get a pretty picture of a keyboard, but to design something that suits the language in an interesting way. But I posted it here to get the communities opinion, and it seems quite clear what it is.

Comment: Since I wrote that meta answer the rules on popularity contests have been tightened up, and I think that is a good thing. I stand by my answer, but I think it is right that popularity contests be judged strictly, to reflect the fact that it is very difficult to write one that is a good fit for the site.

Comment: Although it's possible someone will come up with an ingenious approach to designing a keyboard, the challenge itself seems to lean towards "make me laugh" rather than "impress me". This is why I don't think this is a good fit for the site.

Comment: I'd love to see what keyboards the community comes up with, but I think it would need to be hosted somewhere other than main. For things which are appealing to the PPCG community, but not quite a fit for main, there's [chat]. People often post "mini challenges" which aren't well specified enough to be challenges on main, but can end up inspiring people to write a full challenge.

Comment: I think it's important to keep testing the boundaries of existing winning criteria, and to try to come up with new ones. The people who put the effort into this will have a long run of rejections, but I really hope these don't come across as "don't try".

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/is-there-a-question-format-for-longest-non-repeating-code) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28238/print-the-golden-ratio) gave me an idea, but I'm not quite sure if this can be done at all, or if it is trivial. If it is, maybe point out how it could be changed to be interesting.

## Anti golfing - Write the longest program not repeating any character

Well, it's just what the title says. Finally you're allowed to use as much bytes as possible.

### Conditions

- The code of the program or function should not use any character that is used in the code before.
- Your program should print some sort of result to stdout, or into a file or return a value. You're not allowed to output or return the empty string or only a newline.
- Other than that your program might do anything. Read input, print lots of output, or what you can think of, but you have to explain what it does, of course.
- Only characters in the ASCII range [32 .. 126] and newlines are allowed, which limits the maximal code length to 96 bytes.
- Variable names are only allowed to consist of a single character
- String literals or the like are forbidden. They could be used to hold the unused characters (though they would need two `"` in most languages anyway).
- The same rule applies for similar literal constructs like blocks or what else is there in some languages.
- Even if the length of a string literal would be used to generate a number, it is forbidden.
- Variables can not just be declared and never be used. They have to be reflected in the output somehow.
- If you've read and understood the above rules and still found a loophole and used it, you should go and stand in the corner for a while, thinking about what you've done.

So all in all, only use characters for actual code that does something generating the output, might it be calculating a value or formatting. And don't put unused characters somewhere in your code as a literal. Numbers are an exception, but I guess it's no problem to use them anyway.

I guess you should have a pretty good idea of what would be considered cheating here.

Example in awk

```awk
BEGIN{gsub(a,9);print $j-13+d^c/4*5678%20}
```

> It prints `15.5`, score is 42.
>
> It replaces the empty string `a` with `9` in `$0`, which is the empty string in the beginning. So `$0` becomes `9`.
>
> Then it prints the result of `9-13+1/4*5678%20`.
>
> (`$j` is `$0 (==9)`, because `j` is not defined
>
> `d^c` ist `1`, because `c` and `d` are not defined)

Please don't invent languages for this ;)

The longest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow ASCII 127? That's the unprintable`<DEL>` character. The main problem with this challenge is "only use characters for actual code that does something". This is essentially unenforceable, because there may be arbitrarily complicated no-ops in the code. It's also why most [tag:code-bowling] challenges fail to be popular/interesting.

Comment: Well, I thought about making it a "most votes win" challenge, but I guess that would be unfair for less known users. I don't know what could be done with what you are pointing out.

Comment: I don't think this is a good candidate for a popularity contest. Popularity contests shouldn't be used as a cop out if the actual spec is a bit vague. They work best for challenges where the actual scoring criterion can be well specified but is more easily judged by humans than machines (e.g. "visually approximate a given image with these constraints...").

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to formulate the rules for this. But I think it's not always about finding a winner anyway. Thought this might be fun. Resolved the character 127 situation btw..

Comment: How could I change that rule? I'm thinking about "only use code that contributes to the generation of the output"

Comment: How do you define "contribute"? E.g. [this GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=eyAhJCUmKCkqKy0uLzAxMjM0NTY3ODk6Ozw9Pj9AQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVpbXF1eX2FiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6fH59YCw%3D) program prints the length of the block in `{...}` which is a convenient way to stuff all characters except in `'"#` in there. Do all those random characters actually contribute? In [Slashes](http://esolangs.org/wiki////) everything which isn't an unescaped slash is printed to STDOUT, so as long as I put `\/` together, I can put any characters I want there and they'll all contribute.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this would be covered by forbidding string literals.. might think about extending that rule to blocks. Well, I'm not that fluent at esolangs.

Comment: It's trivial to use all possible 96 bytes. Trust me. If you really want to see the program I'm thinking of, I suppose I could write it, but I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. i have no idea how it would be done, but alright.

Comment: Not to mention this is pretty much a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/hello-world-with-a-twist

Answer (score -2):

## Technologic - Now what's THAT command do??

Daft Punk's song "Technologic" is all about actions that a user or computer does when it's working and being used. You goal is to write a program that has one command we will call the Technologic Command. This command will executes all of the actions like "buy it", "lock it", "code it", and "write it" in the order the lyrics are written on 'it'. What 'it' is is up to you, but you gotta let me know.

## Rules

- Any language can be used.
- The song refers to an 'it'. That can be a block a memory, algorithm, function, file, or anything else a computer can manipulate directly or indirectly.
- You must specify what 'it' is you will be performing these actions on. If you don't, you can only earn a maximum of 160 points.
- Points will be deducted otherwise if a command is not used.
- I'm not aware of any 'buy' command, method, function, subroutine or instruction so use a thesaurus and find the closest word you can actually program. I don't expect the program to actually buy or snap anything. Other words like mail and fax are possible, but not recommended.
- If you have to use a synonym, you are not allowed to use that command again
- Encompassing multiple objects into one artifact does not count. For example, taking the command "name it" literally means you won't be able to name an array of bytes, but you can name a file. Creating an object that holds both a file and an array of bytes is not allowed. That would make this too easy to get the maximum amount of points.

## Scoring

- There are 16 commands with a total possible score of 190 points.
- 10 points for executing a command on the specified 'it' of your choosing (160 total)
- 2 points for executing each command consecutively that references your 'it' (30 total)
- 5 points for executing a command on something other than your 'it'
- -3 points for every command skipped.

## Command List

[lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/daftpunk/technologic.html)

> Buy it, use it, break it, fix it,
> Trash it, change it, mail - upgrade it,
> Charge it, point it, zoom it, press it,
> Snap it, work it, quick - erase it,
> Write it, cut it, paste it, save it,
> Load it, check it, quick - rewrite it,
> Plug it, play it, burn it, rip it,
> Drag and drop it, zip - unzip it,
> Lock it, fill it, call it, find it,
> View it, code it, jam - unlock it,
> Surf it, scroll it, pause it, click it,
> Cross it, crack it, switch - update it,
> Name it, rate it, tune it, print it,
> Scan it, send it, fax - rename it,
> Touch it, bring it, pay it, watch it,
> Turn it, leave it, start - format it.

[code-challange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challange)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29250/discussion-on-answer-by-luminous-sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: I count way more than 16 commands here. There are 16 *lines* each with several commands on them. If we cound the hyphenated commands as two, there are 16 x 4 = 64 commands.

Comment: @steveverrill A slight oversight. haha. I must've counted the lines knowing there were 4 commands on each line and didn't multiply the two together.

Answer (score -2):

## Just Golf 2016 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

(Related: [A Kingdom Hearts VGM challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53678/194)) *Sandbox note: potential duplicate?*

[Just Dance 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Dance_2016) is coming out soon, and I know I'm definitely excited! However, let's take a quick trip back to 2009, when the original Just Dance was released. There are a lot of great songs, but I don't know who sung half of them!

### The Challenge

Write a program that accepts a Just Dance song name from input and outputs the song's artist (as credited in-game.)

Here is the list of all songs and artists from Just Dance 1:
*list pending*

### Rules and Assumptions

- You may assume that the song will always be valid.
- The song's title and artist must be properly capitalized.
- You may not read any external files - the song data must be hardcoded.
- If a song is covered (which several have been for various reasons), the program should return the cover artist (as they are credited in the game.)

### Test Cases

Input: `Eye of the Tiger`
Output: `Survivor`

Input: `Fame`
Output: `Irene Cara`

### Bonuses

- Each game has had one song everyone was really excited about. This year, it's [Ievan Polkka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8SkCkJCAaw) by Hatsune Miku. You get a bonus of -50 points if you accept this song as valid input.
- Just Dance is fun, but why should we stop there? If you additionally accept songs fron the rest of the main series (Just Dance 2, 3, Greatest Hits/Best Of, 4, 2014, and 2015, not including DLC and skipping over any duplicates), you get a whopping **-2009 points**. Here is the full list for those games:
   *list pending*

  - Note that this doesn't include Just Dance 2016 songs.
  - This can be combined with the other bonus to get a total of -2059 bytes.

### Meta Questions

- Are the bonuses too big? (I'm mainly talking about the -2009 point bonus for including every song.)
- Has anything been left out?
- Is this enough of a challenge?

Comment: This looks like a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53678/194 .

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would say it isn't, that one asks for input in the form of a game and boss and returns a song, mine asks for a song and returns an artist. That one also has different scoring rules, and mine requires all items to be implemented.

Comment: They're both "golf this given map / dictionary / associative array". Why would the techniques used be any different?

Comment: @PeterTaylor According to [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1876/38891), the main qualification for duplicates is "Can answers from one question be copied over to the other with little or no modification and still be competitive?". I looked at the answers for the question you linked, and it doesn't seem like either would do very well if those techniques were used in this challenge.

Comment: Would this be [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes.

Answer (score -2):

## Literally just printing the source code

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Wait a second. We already have a [contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good) where you print the source code. Right? Wrong.

### The challenge

Print out the source code. Not to STDOUT, but to a physical printer.

The rules:

- You must write a complete program that prints out its own source code with a printer connected to the computer.
- No STDIN (or input of any kind), STDOUT, or STDERR.
- No standard loopholes (includes no file input). No using lp(r/d) or similar commands.
- The printed code should be a reasonable size (between size 8 and 18) and a legible font (pretty much means no wingdings).
- You may assume that the user doesn't cancel the process and answers affirmatively to any system print dialogs.
- You can assume that the printer works, is ready, doesn't need new ink/paper, etc.
- If the language doesn't support printing, it is ineligible.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code, in bytes, wins.

Comment: This is a trivial extension of the quine challenge. All you have to do is say you're running it on Unix/Linux and pipe the output to `lpr`.

Comment: This needs a much tighter spec on the hardware. E.g. I assume you would consider it cheating to post an ordinary quine and say "On this computer, all console output is also logged to a continuous print spool", but there are computers which are configured like that for audit reasons.

Answer (score -2):

## Restricted "Hello, World!"

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)[hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

The task is very simple, output `Hello, World!` to STDOUT. The thing that makes this different are the rules:

- You need to provide a full functioning program, taking no input and outputting via STDOUT.
- The program must not write anything to STDERR
- The maximum amount of bytes you can use is 50
- The program may only contain printable **[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)** characters. Programs using CP437 and other encoding systems are not allowed
- If a programming language is already used, you cannot use this same language again.
- You cannot use any character of the **prohibited character list**. This is the twist:

#### Prohibited character list (PCL):

The prohibited character list is a list full of characters, which cannot be used in the following programs. For example:

If the list was: `He\.`, you need to create a program, without the characters `H`, `e`, `\` and `.`. **These are not case-sensitive**.

If you succesfully manage to write a program that doesn't use any characters, you may **add new one character** to the prohibited character list.

e.g.

If the old PCL was `He\.`, and you managed to write a program that doesn't use any of these characters, you may add a new character to this list. For example  (whitespace). The new PCL will be `He \.` (notice that the whitespace character is added).

#### Posting Snippet:

This might help you wit posting your submission:

```
#[Language Name], N bytes

 [code]

 (explaination etc.)

 Added character: [char]

 New PCL: [list + new char]
```

In the beginning, the PCL is empty. The last person who managed to create a program without a new program made in 2 days, wins!

---

I'm not really sure if it is flawed or not. If you have any suggestions or comments, feel free to post them below in the comment section :)

Comment: Already exists.

Answer (score -2):

## What day of the week is Christmas?

Christmas is coming quickly, which leads to the question, what day of the week is Christmas this year? But what day of the week is Christmas for any year? Write a program that can do this. **This is code golf, so the shortest code wins!**

However, there is a major twist. **No builtin functions to do this task is allowed!**

**Bonuses**:

1. If the program can handle B.C. years as negative numbers, then -25%
2. If the program prints "The first Christmas!" for an input of -4 (4 B.C. is assumed to be when Jesus Christ was born), then -30 bytes
3. If, for some reason, you really like builtins, +90%! So try NOT to use it!

Comment: The bonus for printing extra should be steeper, or no esolangs are going to go for it.

Comment: @VoteToClose so more like 25% as well?

Comment: No - I'd go static. Plus, this is _really close_ to being a dupe...

Comment: Near dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/day-of-the-week-of-the-next-feb-29th

Comment: It's unspecified what format we should output in or what calendar we should use, and whether -4 should mean 4 BC or 5 BC.

Comment: @ThomasKwa it should be obvious from the sentence that 4 B.C. is -4. Use the Gregorian calendar, output can be in `MMDDYY`

Comment: How is MMDDYY a day of the week?

Comment: @ThomasKwa sorry, it was pretty late when I wrote that so I mistakenly wrote MMDDYY. Just printing the day of the week is fine i.e. print "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.

Answer (score -2):

## Golf A Wiki

### The Challenge

Golf a wiki. A wiki, for the purposes of this contest, is defined as a website with:

- Content editable by all
- Easy CamelCase (defined as a word with two capitals) linking
- Different pages or articles that are the targets of the links

Your wiki can be a self-contained HTML file (e.g. [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com)), or a cgi-bin script (e.g. [SigWik](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?SigWik)).

### Scoring

Your score is the size of your program in bytes, divided by the number of extra features
implemented plus one.

The possible extra features are:

- Page history
- Syntax for "nowiki", that is, something <s>like <\noscript> in HTML</s> that makes the text inside it not be wiki syntax.
- A page list
- A find page facility
- Usernames and passwords (with registering)
- Security levels (requires usernames and passwords, or possibly IPs?)
- Delete pages
- Change page titles
- Redirects
- Random page
- Non-HTML formatting that is not just links *[Should I remove this? I doubt it will be done.]*

Lowest score wins, as this is code golf.

## ***DISCLAIMER***

***ANSWERS WILL PROBABLY CONTAIN MAJOR SECURITY FLAWS. ONLY USE ON PRIVATE PORTS, UNLESS YOU WANT YOUR COMPUTER AND VERY POSSIBLY YOUR WHOLE NETWORK TO GET DESTROYED (FIGURATIVELY).*** [Is this too forceful?]

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I would vote to close this as too broad. Among the problems I see: 1. The two given examples don't seem to be the same thing as each other 2. The complete lack of constraints mean that I could just automatically make every word a link. (This could be fixed by specifying one link syntax: for golfing I quite like the UseModWiki use of CamelCase for links). 3. I think I can get the "text formatting" feature for free by not escaping HTML characters. 4. Needs a big warning "**Answers will likely contain major security flaws and should not be used on ports which are publicly visible**"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll edit when I have time today.

Answer (score -2):

Write a polyglot (a program that works on several languages) that produces the `// this is a comment` output.

### Example (JS + Plain PHP + Plain HTML) (74 / 3 = 24.66 points)

```
// this is a comment<?php ob_start();?><!--
alert("// this is a comment");
```

### Another Example (CoffeeScript + CJam + brainfuck) ()

```
e###-[----->+<]>----..+[--->++<]>.---[->++++<]>.------------.+.++++++++++.+[---->+<]>+++.-[--->++<]>-.++++++++++.+[---->+<]>+++.[->+++<]>+.-[->+++ <]>.+[->+++<]>.++++++++++++.--..--------.+++++++++.++++++.
"// this is a comment"
e### alert "// this is a comment"
```

### Scoring

Your score will be `code byte length / num langs`

The smallest score wins!

Comment: Is there anything that makes this significantly different than [polyglot Hello World](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10695/14215)?

Comment: @Geobits this is more easy, really

Answer (score -2):

## Linear Time Sorting

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

It was another slow day at Initech Inc. when a feature request came in:

```
New Feature: Ability to sort by cash value in the transaction form. But make it a fast one!
```

Well it looks simple.. but what do the requester mean by fast one? Let's call Jim, from sales he probably knows what's going on.

```
Jim: Well you know , our Business Inc. contact is very passionate about 

programming and computer science! In fact he had this idea that we should 

do sorting in how that was called.. linear time?


You: Well you know that's impossible?

Jim: But it was already approved by their cto and all! You need to do something
```

You and Jim came up with a plan.. nobody will notice if that big of a list isn't sorted enough, right?

## Your task

Your task is to write a linear time sorting program. It will be scored on accuracy of the sort as compared to list sorted by regular sorting algorithm but it must work on O(N) time in the worst case, where N is length of the input.

Input will be in the form of list of string-double tuples, e.g:

```
[("aaaa",2.0) , ("aaba",1.0)]
```

The program should sort on the number value of the tuple, i.e. in the above case the order should be reversed.
There may be multiple inputs with the same double values, but no string value is repeated. In the event that two inputs have the same integer value the perfect solution is to keep the order as it is.
The double value may be any floating-point value that fits in 8 byte double precision variable. NaNs should be placed at the end of the list.

The score is calculated as number of "bubble sort operations" (switch an element with the next/previous element) needed to achieve perfect output from the output of your algorithm.

## Sandbox Worries

Well I don't know how clear my explanation of challenge was and if it is interesting to the PPCG crowd.

Obviously there is a need for testing program and test cases.

Comment: How big will the test cases be? If you pick a fixed size, the response will be "n passes of bubble sort where n is the size of the largest test". Bam, linear with perfect score.

Comment: @JanDvorak I rephrased the scoring sentence to more reflect what I meant. In that case the score wouldn't be perfect as after just n switches the list wouldn't be the most ordered. EDIT: I think I understood it now. Well I think you can somehow exclude answers like that with some caveats in the rules, like "Your algorithm cannot make any assumtions about length of the input"

Comment: I don't make any assumptions. It sorts every array up until the largest test case correctly and all other arrays partially.

Comment: An algorithm that fares better than n-pass bubble sort is to do a level-n mergesort. If the length exceeds 2^n, sort each [k::len/2^n] subarray separately.

Comment: But then you're making assumptions based on the size of the test cases - if somehow the test cases were changed (but still fitting the rules) to test cases which are much longer (for example you prepared for max 10 element list and you get 100000 element list) your program isn't linear.

Comment: The problem with a spec is that it cannot change once you've posted the challenge, and you can't define "making assumptions based on the size of the test cases". You can't even ban all magic numbers - I can simply use functions merge1 .. merge20

Comment: It isn't the spec - the way the test cases used to grade the result are constructed is described but do I have to post the test cases (but those used to score) themselves?

Comment: You need to define the test cases, and you can't change them based on the answers (if only because updating the score of every answer would be a nuisance). Maybe you could ask for asymptotic behavior, but that can be surprisingly hard to measure.

Comment: Hidden test cases are a problem as well, because then we can't test the submissions after you're gone.

Comment: The idea was to pregenerate some test cases (undisclosed) and some test cases that are disclosed (for testing purposes during the coding) and then do a cutoff time for the challenge where all the solutions are tested against the undisclosed challenges. Also obviously after the cutoff time the test cases would be disclosed.

Comment: 1. Most real-life data types *can* be sorted in linear time, so the premise of the question seems badly flawed. 2. "*Input will be in the form of list of string-double tuples ... There may be multiple inputs with the same integer values*" Huh? Where do the integer values come from? 3. "*The double value may be any floating-point value*" Where do NaNs sort?

Comment: 1. The idea is that the data may be the worst case for any algorithm that can achieve linear sorting time 2. It was a typo 3. At the end - I will put it into the question

Comment: Why does the input being worst case make any difference? The solution will still be perfect, so you'll need a tie-breaker to separate every single answer.

Answer (score -2):

## Make a quine without using string literals [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

A quine is a computer program that prints out it's own source code to stdout. Your task is to make one that doesn't use string literals.

You cannot:

- Have any empty program
- Read your source code directly or indirectly (i.e. form a file)
- Use error messages to print out the source code
- Rely on language features to print out the source
- Relying on a REPL environment

A string literal is a:

- String type (obvious)
- Number used to store the character (sorry BF!)
- Other predefined constant

You are encouraged to compute your own source code.

Comment: This hits two of the "things to avoid when writing challenges": [do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/194) and [popcons](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8134/194). (I assume it's an attempt to finesse a third: [generalised quines](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/194)). It also has some fairly bad phrasing: what language can print anything without using "*language features*"? In what way does BF use literals? How many languages can compute *anything* without using at least one constant?

Answer (score -2):

## 2 Pass Hello world

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)

There you go, your first "Hello world" is displayed on your terminal. You think about your next step into becoming a wizard.

You've heard about this fancy new programming language, but you're not sure you understand it perfectly. So you want to go over a new "Hello world" tutorial again.

**How boring!**

Instead you have a good idea, using your knowledge of the **first** programming language to create a "Hello world" program in the **second** programming language.

Exemple:

```
console.log('print "Hello world"');
```

Evaluated in javascript output:

```
print "Hello world"
```

Which, evaluated in python 2.X output:

```
"Hello world"
```

Nice, but, can it be **shorter**?

Comment: We have a tag for multi-language challenges, [tag:polyglot].

Comment: Pyth: [`\H`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=\H&debug=0) (Guess what the second language is)

Comment: Maybe add a scoring mechanism by how many languages it works in? e.g. `console.log('print("puts\'Hello, World!\'")')` would score `len(submission)/num_languages_it_works_in`?

Comment: Then the submission above would score 0.

Comment: (To OP) Maybe you would need to add some more rules

Comment: @KennyLau no? `2/2 = 1`

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ It can be fed into itself for one more pass...

Comment: I didn't want to add any recursive mechanism, because the end goal should be to display "Hello world" but a more than 2 language is a great idea.

Comment: I don't see how you will be able to come up with a good scoring system for this. Using two esolangs / two times the same esolang will result in 1/2 bytes answers right away.

Comment: @KennyLau, what rules do you generally add to a incomplete challenge? we thought adding a time/memory limit for the execution, but seems irrelevant...

Comment: This is really closely related to several other challenges we've had on the site, such as [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37357/42963) one and [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7261/42963) one. You'll need to be very careful to not make it a duplicate.

Comment: Also [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68820/42963), which is practically a duplicate, just with numbers instead of "Hello, world."

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen all this, I guess I'll start searching for another idea instead ;)

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG! (I forgot to mention that earlier). Hope you enjoy yourself here!

Answer (score -2):

### Cops and robbers : Programmers/Hackers

- This challenge is quite different from my previous challenges. This challenge is an endless competition between robbers and cops, which are respectively hackers and programmers. One of them will ever win!!!
- This will evolve to code de/obfuscating when it gets to the higher stages: a skillful programmer who is struggling to save his program from a sourcecode-mangling attempted by a cunning "robber" who tries to impose his existence by patching his name instead of the name of the "programmer" in the output console without changing anything else in the code. The story begins this way:
- Programmer is at the point of executing his recently made C code, so he included this trivial line to show off:

*C (1)*

```
    printf("[Programmer's username]")
```

After executing this program programmer saw this on the screen:

```
[Robber's username]
```

which indicates the presence of some evil code at the compiler level that compromises his code, which follows:

*Matlab (2)/parser*

```
      a=findstr(code,'printf(''[Programmer's username]'')'); if a code(a:20)='printf(''[Robber's username]'')';end
```

The programmer cannot modify the counter-program in the compiler, so he must rather change the program content to escape the twiddling:

*PHP (3)*

```
      $a='[programmer's username]';echo $a;
```

The score is now 3, which is the number of steps from the beginning. The current user would win only if the hacker did not figure out something like:

*PHP/Regex(pcre flavor) (4)*

```
      $code=ereg_replace("(\$\w)\='programmer';(.*?);echo\s\1","\1\='robber';\2;echo\s\1",$code)
```

Since the solution above does not satisfy the rules (see the bottom of this question), the score stays unchanged, and the programmer can make a counter example, and take out the score from last submitter with a penalty on his score equivalent of how much he earned in the earlier level, where the counter example can be something as:

*PHP (4)*

```
      $a='programmer';$b=$a;$a='unrelated';echo $a;
```

Or he can adjust his program in higher scale to escape all the regex-trapping in a superior range, So the cycle goes on until no post can be added and the last submitter **before the end of June** is declared a potential winner meanwhile.

The hacker can also fix his regex and regain his score, so the recent scoring will be abrogated from programmer.

*Perl/dynamic-regex (4)*

```
local @a=('');

sub check{
  if (grep {$_ eq @_[1]} @a)  
   {push @a,@_[0]; } 
  elsif  (grep {$_ eq @_[0]} @a)   {
    my @del_indexes = grep { @a[$_] eq @_[0] } 0..$#a;
    foreach $item (@del_indexes) {
     splice (@a,$item,1);
    }
  }   
return 1;
}

sub actor{
if (grep {$_ eq @_[0]} @a)
 {return "print robber";}
else
 {return "print ".@_[0];}
}


sub initiate{
push(@a,@_[0]);
return 1;
}

$code =~ s/(((\w+)\="programmer"(??{initiate($3);}))|(print\s(\w+))|((\w+)\=(\w+)(?{check(($7),($8));})(?1)))/print($2);actor($5)/pegmx;
```

As you can see [this Perl program](http://rextester.com/ZGPKD97343) prints b in the first case because the variable `b` is compromised after the first assignment, but in the second case the regex modifies the output because `d` receives the target-string transitively. Let's just stop here and not mess the fun (of course, if there will be some).

### Scoring and rules

**How is the score counted ?**

- Any hacker/programmer is scored for his code as the actual level `L` the game is on.
- A partial dynamic regex within the core of the program is scored `L + (2^L)/log(length of program + length of characters which do not belong to the regex))`, where the `log` is base 2.
  For the second example of level (4) the length of the compacted program is 480, and the length of regex is 136, so the score is `4+2^4/log2(480+480-136) ~= 4+16/9.6`
- A fully functional regex as in the first example level (4) is scored `L + (2^L)/log(length of regex)`, where the `log` is base 2, in that case `S = 4 + 2^4 / log(91) ~= 4+16/6.5`
- Scores are added progressively to submitters, and when a level is surpassed with no regex, it is still open for scores, while the actual winner remains unchanged.
- A penalty on a certain-leveled score when the regex/parser is revealed out of rules and the game is regressed to this stage until the issue is fixed, rules are cited below:

**Rules:**

- The main rule: the hacker-program must compromise an output to the console, which is the username of the programmer. Any other behavior is unaccepted simply because a string variable of [programmer's username] can be used in other order rather than printing, a counter-example is easy, converting the string to integer then use it for arithmetic calculations that harms the main program once intentionally modified.
- Also one of the following factors declared by any counter-example bans the targeted flawed regex/parser as non rule-complying:

  - The regex/parser prints anything other than a chosen string preferably set as the username of the robber.
  - The regex/parser generates a program which does not compile.
  - The regex/parser does not print anything, or compromises a segment of code that is needed for tasks other than printing .
- The variable which stores the program is named `code` by default, also you may assume that is one-liner, and any non-significant spaces are omitted, and that it is fully working by default.
- The regex/parser deals with one variant of one code proportion in a comprehensive way, i.e. if a `print` function is used, that encompasses all printing functions in all languages `puts`,`disp`,..etc. Also, code separators can be unified to one characterL either `,` or `;` or a significant space needlessly of enumerating all keywords/syntaxes, this is not a contest about a working code in a specific programming language.
- To prevent endless program/regex loops let's just not making a jokey sequence as `a='programmer';print a` / `/(\w)\='programmer';print\s\1/` /  `a='programmer';b=a;print b` / `/(\w)\='programmer';(\w)\=\1;print\s\2/` because the first person who makes a regex/parser which palliates to a same replicated idea will take out all attributed scores to this idea from their owners, so any anaphoric sequences like this in addition that they are set to same level, they are unneeded.
- Any language that uses pointers/addresses/classes like C++ are welcome, as long as they help to evade the hacker.

Comment: Please, for the love of god, spell things correctly. In the first bit alone I spotted a ton of spelling mistakes without even looking for them. Also, that whole first list is... basically impossible to understand, at least for me. Maybe use full sentences?

Comment: Have you seen our [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenges?  It sounds like that is what you are trying to do here.  That said, there are a *couple* of problems with the spec:  Defining what parts of the language counts as a "partial regex" or "full regex" is really tough, especially when we get into esoteric languages.

Comment: Could you add a short summary to the post? I don't understand what the actual task here is. Is this a `cops-and-robbers` or `answer-chaining` challenge, or something entirely different?

Comment: i will see what cops and robbers is

Comment: @NathanMerrill this is not a code golf so i dont see the point of introducing esolangs here

Comment: @Agawa001 Esoteric languages are still useful outside of golfing.  You can use them to make it tough for regexes to match.

Comment: The introduction is very long and after reading it I have no idea what the task is. I would have to vote to close this as "Unclear what you're asking" in its current state.

Comment: So what's the core mechanic? Is this an answer-chaining question where answers must alternate programmer and hacker? But if the programmer can change language at will, how can the hacker hope to win?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes it is answer chaining but the last submitter can post two consecutive answers and be the robber and cop themselves, the programmer change his code, hacker changes his regex taken consideration of all last regex/parsers.

Comment: I have no idea what this challenge is supposed to be. The very little explanation of the concept is muddled by spelling and grammar issues. Please, learn English spelling and grammar before trying to write a challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor refer at the 4th rule, procedures which accomplishes a specific task in different languages are dealt as one thing, this is not a challenge about checking language-syntaxes, when a programmer changes language, consider all previous regex/parsers changed to trap same functionnalities of previous code on the new language.

Answer (score -2):

### Challenge

Write a program that takes an numerical input `n` and outputs the `n`th number that is not a perfect square.

### Rules

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least bytes wins.

Comment: What's the maximum expected input? Does it expect `0`? How do we handle `0`? Is there a requirement on the efficiency for large inputs? Also give some example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Here's some test cases I just generated: `1->2,2->3,3->5,4->6,5->7,6->8,7->10,8->11,9->12,10->13,11->14,12->15,13->17,14->18,15->19,16->20,17->21,18->22,19->23,20->24,21->26,22->27,23->28,24->29,25->30,26->31,27->32,28->33,29->34,30->35,31->37,32->38,33->39,34->40,35->41,36->42,37->43,38->44,39->45,40->46,41->47,42->48,43->50,44->51,45->52,46->53,47->54,48->55,49->56,50->57,51->58,52->59,53->60,54->61,55->62,56->63,57->65,58->66,59->67,60->68,61->69,62->70,63->71,64->72,65->73,66->74,67->75,68->76,69->77,70->78,71->79,72->80` Is this the function you expect?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Can you address my other questions please? Namely, the largest expected input and how to handle input of `0`.

Answer (score -2):

## Generate all variations of a string with every combination of upper and lower case for each vowel but leaving consonants and order of letters unchanged.

[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

This is a simplified analog of a problem I've thought about a few times over the years based around variant spellings in different spoken languages.

Input is a text string. Output is an array of all variations of the text string.

A "variation" means the same letters in the same order but for each vowel letter in the string we generate a version of that string with the vowel in uppercase and the vowel in lowercase.

No variation should be included more than once. No legal variation may be omitted.

## Example

### Input

`codegolf`

### Output

- `codegolf`
- `codegOlf`
- `codEgolf`
- `codEgOlf`
- `cOdegolf`
- `cOdegOlf`
- `cOdEgolf`
- `cOdEgOlf`

The winner shall be the **most elegant as voted by the community**.

"Elegant" includes that the algorithm should be optimal in terms of Big O notation, should be concise, should be idiomatic making good use of available features of the implementation language.

Length of code characters or bytes is not relevant.

Programming language is open.

Comment: "most elegant as voted by the community." I doubt many answers to such a challenge will be deemed elegant.

Comment: Really? Anything to suggest instead? Just "best" is usually no good for Stack Exchange...

Comment: Code golf version of this challenge: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80995/8478. That said, I don't think "most elegant" makes a good popularity contest and is very likely to be downvoted and closed almost instantly. If you're looking for elegant solutions, this might not be the right community in the first place though. You could write your own solution and post it on Code Revew to ask for improvements. We generally require objective winning criteria for our challenges, and popularity contests are in a weird place where you need to come up with something really good for it to be accepted.

Comment: Hmm well OK whatever.

Answer (score -2):

## Oh noes! A site redesign is eating my privileges!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

---

PPCG is graduating and will soon receive a new design. Unfortunately for everbody except [some people](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), the new design will also mean [losing privileges due to higher reputation requirements](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2848/523).

Now, losing some privileges is a small sacrifice for the *Magnificent Glorious Site Redesign®©™*, but… How much do we stand do lose?

### The challenge

Your program / function receives a reputation level (e.g. `535`). Output the privileges that are [currently available](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to it, but will not be available [after the redesign](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/).

#### Output

Output can be either an array or a string that's separated by a delimiter. The delimiter may not be any of `A-Za-z<space>`. Multi-character delimiters may end in a space, though.

If there are no matches, your program should output either an empty array or a [falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/13486) value.

#### Examples

Input

```js
25000
```

Output

```js
[]
```

Input

```js
24999
```

Output

```js
["access to site analytics"]
```

Input

```js
2000
```

Output

```js
["access to moderator tools","approve tag wiki edits","cast close and reopen votes","create tag synonyms"]
```

Input

```js
535
```

Output

```js
["cast close and reopen votes"]
```

Input

```js
350
```

Output

```js
["access review queues"]
```

Input

```js
5
```

Output

```js
[]
```

Input

```js
4
```

Output

```js
["participate in meta"]
```

<sup>Deliberately ignoring [the facts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7084/13486) in the last example.</sup>

#### Available privileges

For convenience, here is a JSON array with available privileges and the required reputation before / after:

```js
[[5000,25000,"access to site analytics"],[4000,20000,"trusted user"],[3500,15000,"protect questions"],[2000,10000,"access to moderator tools"],[1500,5000,"approve tag wiki edits"],[500,3000,"cast close and reopen votes"],[1250,2500,"create tag synonyms"],[1000,2000,"edit questions and answers"],[750,1000,"established user"],[1000,1000,"create gallery chat rooms"],[350,500,"access review queues"],[150,300,"create tags"],[250,250,"view close votes"],[125,125,"vote down"],[100,100,"edit community wiki"],[100,100,"create chat rooms"],[75,75,"set bounties"],[50,50,"comment everywhere"],[20,20,"talk in chat"],[15,15,"flag posts"],[15,15,"vote up"],[10,10,"remove new user restrictions"],[10,10,"create wiki posts"],[1,5,"participate in meta"],[1,1,"create posts"]]
```

At index `0` is the reputation before, at index `1` is the reputation after. <sub>(The privilege *reduce ads* (200 reputation) is not available to beta sites and therefore not included in this list.)</sub>

<sub>Standard [I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/13486) and [loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/13486) rules apply.</sub>

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5502/194). It's borderline whether this adds enough to not count as a duplicate: I would vote that it does, but I wouldn't cast my supervote.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm thinking of changing the challenge to allow submissions to download the privilege page. I guess that would make it distinct enough.

Comment: Turns it into a hybrid parse-HTML and merge data sources question. Yes, I think that's novel. You should make it very clear that the answers should keep working after the contents of the privilege page are updated to show the new rep levels; and possibly you should take a backup copy of the page in case of future addition of new privileges.

Answer (score -2):

**Plot Partial Node Network**

I have a 440*3 matrix that looks like:

```
1   144 Title1
1   152 Title2
1   135 Title3
2   3 Title4
2   12 Title5
2   107 Title6
2   31 Title7
3   4 Title8
3   147 Title9
3   0 Title10
4   end Title11
4   0 Title12
4   0 Title13
5   6 Title14
5   7 Title15
5   10 Title16
5   9 Title17
```

The left column are the starting points eg in the app all the 1's on the left would be on the same page. They lead to three choices, pages 144,152,135. These pages can each then lead to another page, and so on until the middle column says 'end'.

**challenge**
Each number has an associated title in column three. I would like to have a function whereby if you input a given title it will plot all the possible starting points and their associated paths that will lead there. This should be a lot smaller and therefore graph friendly.

**Example**
e.g.

```
44  234  tes
186  187  Frac
187  154  Low
154  end  Coll
99  101  adf
23   52   Med
52   11   Lip
11   42   AAA
42   154   BBB
154   end  Coll
```

**EDIT** - I added to the example. In the winning entry these new nodes will not be plotted as they do not lead to Coll.

I made this example to show how column 1 leads to a value in column 2 which then refers to a value in column 1 until you reach the end. Different starting points can ultimately lead to different length paths to same destination. so this would look sometigng like: 
[image: All paths leads to Coll]

So here, I wanted to see how you could go from all start points to 'Coll'

**Input**
A data.frame like that illustrated (with not relevant rows included) and a given title

**Rules**
-any language is fine as long as it will easy work with tab separated data laid out as shown

**Output**
A graph like the one included for a given title

**Win Criteria**
Shortest Runtime to make a png with graph

Comment: A question should have one challenge, not two. And a challenge should ideally have one goal, not two; and should certainly have a clear description not only of the input but also of the output.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for this. I've edited accordingly

Comment: [Similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70201/194), [also](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11693/194).

Comment: they're similar but not the same. they dont solve the problem of just plotting the rows that lead to Coll.

Comment: i edited example to clarify this Peter :)

Comment: I do like this question, but I currently do not support it as a question, due to it being unclear as to exactly what the png can and can not look like. I do support graphical output questions.

Answer (score -2):

## The Library Problem

Bob has a very annoying problem. His boss told him to write a cat program that redirects the standard input to the standard output. But he recently installed a virus on his computer which deleted every libraries on it.

Now he really need to create this program without using any library (even the language standard library). It need to run at least on one operating system with one architecture.

## Challenge

Write a program or that redirects the standard input to the standard output without using any library or external program/command to run to help Bob. You can use system calls and interrupts for example, but your program must not run in ring 0 mode (most operating systems like Microsoft Windows or GNU/Linux have kernels which prevent programs from doing anything, but MS-DOS for example let programs do everything).

- **Input**: anything (text, binary)
- **Output**: exactly the same as the input

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Example Input and Output

First:

- Input: `Hello, world!`
- Output: `Hello, world!`

Second:

- Input: `...`
- Output: `...`

Comment: That's just [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62230/8478) isn't it?

Comment: @MartinEnder This challenge is about doing a cat program **without using any library or external command/program** even the standard library built with the language.

Comment: So everything would need to be written in assembly or equivalent?

Comment: @TimmyD Yes for example, but I think there are other lower-level languages which allow this.

Comment: In that case it just seems like the same challenge limited to a small set of languages? In that case it would probably still be considered a duplicate and the usual course of action is to offer a bounty for the language you want to see a solution in.

Comment: @MartinEnder You need a lower-level language but it doesn't mean that every program made using a lower-level language works with this challenge. See this answer for example which uses a function from the standard library http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62309/54187.

Answer (score -2):

## Alphabet Circle

<sub>This post got very negative feedback, so it's apparent that it needs tweaking in the sandbox before I attempt to repost it on PCG</sub>

---

With all the new alphabet xxx challenges, I've decided I'll give my own challenge.

**Input**

An Integer, (or your languages equivalent) `r`, such that 0 < r ≤ 26. (you don't need to validate this)

**Output**

An alphabet circle. Must meet the following criteria:

- Smoothly interpolated from A at the center and Z at the edge.
- Each point in the circle is the distance from the center  offset so that 0 = A, 1 = B, 2 = C etc...
- Be printed to STDOUT

**Examples**

**r=26**

[image]

**r=15**

[image]

**Boilerplate**

Anonymous classes and functions are fine. General Code Golf rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins!<sup><sup><sup>Except Jelly</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Please remove the `Except Jelly` part...

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg no

Comment: Disallowing language are [a thing to avoid when writing challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/53745)

Comment: It's triple super scripted, it's a joke. I'm not removing it. Get a sense of humour!

Comment: Since you mention negative feedback, my negative feedback would be that a glut of recent challenges on theme X (in this case alphabet layout) is a strong reason to avoid more challenges on theme X for a while, not to add to the pile. Variety is good. If I were you I'd hold this challenge for a month. Moving onto positive feedback, the spec needs to define the desired layout more clearly. I can't work out what the precise criterion is for which letter to place in each space.

Comment: If a position is not an integer distance from the centre, should the distance be truncated, rounded up/down or something else?

Comment: Could you specify whether leading/trailing spaces and newlines are permitted/required? Does the circle need to be framed in a square of matching size, or can it always be in a square of a fixed maximum size?

Comment: I think this would work best as a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] just for the size 26 pattern. That'd avoid any issues with defining how to interpolate the circles (or, indeed, defining the pattern generally, as it would be defined via stating the intended output).

Answer (score -2):

## Nasty Nasty Bugs

Help the programmer provide detailed instructions to the team on how to deal with bug fixes.

The team's goto instructions for dealing with bugs goes like this.

```
For the twelfth bug of Christmas, my team leader said to me 

    Tell them it's a feature
    Say it's not supported
    Change the documentation
    Blame it on the hardware
    Find a way around it
    Say they need an upgrade
    Reinstall the software
    Ask for a dump
    Run with the debugger
    Try to reproduce it
    Ask them how they did it and
    See if they can do it again.
```

The indentation must comply with the teams coding standards, so it may either be tabs or four spaces (since the team's editors expand tabs to spaces anyway). The team lead doesn't mind a leading or trailing newline, but there is no tolerance for the dreaded standard loopholes. Also the office is a bit cramped so the code needs to be as small as possible. 
These lyrics are moderately adapted from http://www.manbottle.com/humor/twelve_bugs_of_christmas
[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: What is the actual challenge? A [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] to reproduce the quoted text verbatim?

Comment: whoops should have tagged it as such @PeterTaylor

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of a pattern here. What does this add over other kgc questions? (And why isn't it a dupe of the Rickroll challenge?)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I could put all 12 verses of the 12 bugs of christmas in. But then it could be a dupe of the 12 days of christmas challenge

Answer (score -2):

## Return True to Win - Counter [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

*Original credit goes to [this](https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue) site, which you should all check out*

Write the shortest javascript code to pass as parameter `f` to  function `counter` such that it returns true:

```
function counter(f) {
    var a = f(), b = f();
    return a() == 1 && a() == 2 && a() == 3
        && b() == 1 && b() == 2;
}
```

I'm considering also making this a series with all the rest of the challenges on the site, where each one gets harder

Comment: Given the lack of a terms of use page on the site, the code on that site is copyrighted, with no provisions for reproduction. This is copyright violation.

Comment: In addition to Mego's note regarding copyright, language-specific challenges are not typically well-received by the community.

Answer (score -2):

## Crab Canon

A crab canon is a piece of music where the same tune is played backwards and forwards at the same time, and it somehow sounds nice. The most famous example is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ykl2tJwZM) by Bach. In *Godel, Escher, Bach*, Douglas Hofstadter wrote a [crab canon in dialog form](https://txti.es/crab-canon), in which the characters of Achilles and the Tortoise alternate lines, with one set of lines being the same as the other set except backwards. Somehow, it makes sense.

The challenge is to write a program inspired by this art form. The only requirement is that there has to be some sort of reversal of the source code involved. For example, you could make a program that:

- Prints its own source code, but backwards
- Does the same thing when reversed
- Both of the above at the same time
- Or make up something creative and wow the voters!

The reversal can happen on pretty much whatever level you want: lines of code, characters, characters within lines, or whatever makes sense for your language. The Hofstadter Crab Canon has some small changes between the two sets of lines for the sake of coherence, you can do something similar if you feel it is necessary.

**This is a popularity contest, the answer with the most votes wins.**

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: This is without a doubt too broad. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info

Comment: @PeterTaylor FYI there's something wrong with that link's formatting

Comment: There isn't any formatting. I just pasted the link directly. And it works for me.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hmm, seems to have fixed itself...

Answer (score -2):

### Petals around the Roses

Given 5 numbers from 1 to 6, calculate the number of Roses, Petals and Roots. Try guessing the formulas yourself by visiting http://jetpackshark.com/RPS before reading anybody's answers. (The dice-like display is significant.)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins.

Comment: If you're looking for a "solve-the-puzzle" challenge, the site for that is [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).  If you want it to be a [tag:code-golf], then please include a formula for how the roses, petals, and roots are calculated.

Comment: Or at the very list a definition of roses, petals, and roots in this context. At present this question makes no more sense than the output of a Markov text generation process.

Answer (score -2):

### Write a Brainfuck interpreter in Brainfuck

Since [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is known to be turing-complete, it is possible to write a Brainfuck interpreter in Brainfuck. This is what you're supposed to do.

You will get the input from the standard input and output to the standard output. This is a programming-puzzle, so the length is not top priority, however if there are multiple solutions, the shortest one wins!

Comment: BF interpreter (non language specific) challenge has already been done, and language exclusive challenges generally aren't good

Answer (score -2):

## Щoгкeгs of tиe щoгld, цпite!

## Iпtгodцctioп

Iп tиe Iпteгпets, people sometimes liкe to stчlize tиeiг posts дs if tиeч щeгe щгitteп iп д diffeгeпt scгipt. Tидпкs to tиe пotoгietч of Soviet Яцssiд, tиe Cчгчlic scгipt seems to бe pдгticцlдгlч fдvoгed.

Бцt щидt cдп д пext-dooг tгoll do if tиeч'гe пot д pгogгдmmeг? Mдпцдllч гeplдciпg eдcи дпd eveгч letteг cдп бe qцite tedioцs...

## Cидlleпge

Чoц дгe to щгite д pгogгдm tидt щill дccept дп дгбitгдгilч loпg iпpцt of Lдtiп cидгдcteгs дпd sцбstitцte some letteгs щitи similдгlч looкiпg Cчгчlics cидгдcteгs. Tиe oцtpцt sиoцld бe ideпticдl to tиe oцtpцt pгodцced бч tиe folloщiпg цпgolfed C# scгipt:

```
цsiпg Sчstem;
цsiпg Sчstem.Collectioпs.Geпeгic;
цsiпg Sчstem.Liпq;
 
pцбlic clдss Test
{
    pцбlic stдtic void Mдiп()
    {
        Dictioпдгч<cидг, cидг> tгдпs = пeщ Dictioпдгч<cидг, cидг>{
            {'A', 'д'},
            {'a', 'д'},
            {'B', 'Б'},
            {'b', 'б'},
            {'N', 'И'},
            {'b', 'и'},
            {'K', 'К'},
            {'k', 'к'},
            {'N', 'П'},
            {'n', 'п'},
            {'R', 'Я'},
            {'r', 'г'},
            {'U', 'Ц'},
            {'u', 'ц'},
            {'W', 'Щ'},
            {'w', 'щ'},
            {'Y', 'Ч'},
            {'y', 'ч'}
        };
 
        stгiпg s; щиile((s = Coпsole.ЯeдdLiпe()) != пцll) {
            Coпsole.ЩгiteLiпe(
                пeщ stгiпg(s.Select(c => tгдпs.CoпtдiпsКeч(c) ? tгдпs[c] : c).
                    Toдггдч()
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Tиe sиoгtest code щiпs.

## Exдmple Iпpцt дпd Oцtpцt

Iпpцt:

> As we know, the goal of every struggle is victory. But if the
> proletariat is to achieve victory, all the workers, irrespective of
> nationality, must be united. Clearly, the demolition of national
> barriers and close unity between the Russian, Georgian, Armenian,
> Polish, Jewish and other proletarians is a necessary condition for the
> victory of the proletariat of all Russia.
>
> We are for the withering away of the state, and at the same time we
> stand for the strengthening of the dictatorship of the proletariat,
> which represents the most powerful and mighty of all forms of the
> state which have existed up to the present day. The highest
> development of the power of the state, with the object of preparing
> the conditions of the withering away of the state: that is the Marxist
> formula. Is it "contradictory"? Yes, it is "contradictory." But this
> contradiction is a living thing and wholly reflects the Marxist
> dialectic.

Oцtpцt:

> дs щe кпoщ, tиe goдl of eveгч stгцggle is victoгч. Бцt if tиe
> pгoletдгiдt is to дcиieve victoгч, дll tиe щoгкeгs, iггespective of
> пдtioпдlitч, mцst бe цпited. Cleдгlч, tиe demolitioп of пдtioпдl
> бдггieгs дпd close цпitч бetщeeп tиe Яцssiдп, Geoгgiдп, дгmeпiдп,
> Polisи, Jeщisи дпd otиeг pгoletдгiдпs is д пecessдгч coпditioп foг tиe
> victoгч of tиe pгoletдгiдt of дll Яцssiд.
>
> Щe дгe foг tиe щitиeгiпg дщдч of tиe stдte, дпd дt tиe sдme time щe
> stдпd foг tиe stгeпgtиeпiпg of tиe dictдtoгsиip of tиe pгoletдгiдt,
> щиicи гepгeseпts tиe most poщeгfцl дпd migиtч of дll foгms of tиe
> stдte щиicи идve existed цp to tиe pгeseпt dдч. Tиe иigиest
> developmeпt of tиe poщeг of tиe stдte, щitи tиe oбject of pгepдгiпg
> tиe coпditioпs of tиe щitиeгiпg дщдч of tиe stдte: tидt is tиe Mдгxist
> foгmцlд. Is it "coпtгдdictoгч"? Чes, it is "coпtгдdictoгч." Бцt tиis
> coпtгдdictioп is д liviпg tиiпg дпd щиollч гeflects tиe Mдгxist
> diдlectic.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thanks for using the Sandbox! Unfortunately, this challenge is essentially the same as [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60443/31625). Also, please don't write your specs in this "stylised" manner. It greatly hurts the searchability of your post.

Comment: Your code is also stylized. Does your code run properly?

Comment: @ColdGolf And do you think I'd stylize my post by hand?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman OK, thank you. I now see my challenge was pointless and won't post it to the main.

Comment: Nothing is pointless: now you you know more and can come up with a better challenge! :)

Comment: @ColdGolf OK you were right, I messed up the stylization. `{'b', 'и'}` - here is a bug. Sorry.

Comment: @gaazkam Does your code, with the stylized `цsiпg Sчstem;`, run properly?

Comment: @ColdGolf I regard people of CodeGolf intelligent enough to find out they'd have to unstylize this code ^^ :)

Comment: @gaazkam I see.

Answer (score -2):

#### Alphabet ripple

You must print out this exact text:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyyyyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxxxxxxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwwwwwwwwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvvvvvvvvvvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuuuuuuuuuuuutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrsttttttttttttttsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrssssssssssssssssrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnopppppppppppppppppppppponmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnoooooooooooooooooooooooonmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjihgfedcba
abcdefghiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiihgfedcba
abcdefghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhgfedcba
abcdefggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggfedcba
abcdeffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffedcba
abcdeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeedcba
abcddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddcba
abccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccba
abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbba
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

#### Specs

- You may do it in all-uppercase instead of all-lowercase.
- A single leading and trailing newline are allowed
- You may not output an array of strings - the delimiter must be a newline

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Program with lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Seriously, another alphabet challenge ._.

Comment: Duplicate, too lazy to find.

Comment: @LeakyNun you're too lazy to search through your own challenges...?

Comment: @trichoplax I don't feel like wasting my time to search for the duplicate.

Comment: @LeakyNun I knew what you meant - I was just making a poor joke that you would only need to search your own challenges since you wrote every alphabet challenge...

Comment: @LeakyNun, this [Show tree rings age](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57442/show-tree-rings-age)?

Comment: @LeakyNun what exactly is the duplicate? I'd like to know.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87064/48934)

Answer (score -2):

## The Note-Takers Dream

> ### Meta
>
> This challenge requires more than most challenges. Is it to much?

The goal here is simple. Turn my notes into text. To this end, any tool or web service may be employed.

### Specification

- **Input**

  - An image of handwritten notes, stored an some data structure (this structure is flexible)
  - This image will be a direct, over-head shot of a single page of graph paper
- **Notes**

  - The notes are taken on graph paper with one character per box
  - The characters will be printable ASCII
  - An empty box should be considered as a single *Space* character
  - There is an implicit *New Line* character between each row
- **Output**

  - A string of the text represented in the image
  - This image should be trimmed of leading white space
  - Trailing white space is fine
- **Score**

  - The score is the sum of the [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between required outputs and actual outputs
  - Lowest score wins

### Test Cases

Coming soon. . .

Comment: Mathematica will win, and everyone else will weep

Comment: So basically http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28207/194 with a larger character set and probably a smaller test set. It's effectively a dupe IMO.

Comment: Golfing in ABBYY FineReader Engine has never been so exciting.

Answer (score -2):

## Print the name of the language

The goal of this challenge, as implied in the title, is to print the name of the language with a program in said language, in as few bytes as possible.

But that would be too easy, right ?

So to add a litle bit of challenge, you are not allowed to use any characters included in the language's name.

## Rules

- Each submission must be a full program.
- The program must take no input, and print the name of the language to STDOUT plus an optional trailing newline, and nothing else.
- The program must not write anything to STDERR.
- [Usual loophole rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- Submissions are scored in bytes, in an appropriate encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program (in bytes) wins.

## Sandbox

After checking, I don't think this question is a dupe.
Are there any grammatical mistakes ? (English isn't my first language)
Are there any rules that should be added (like banning languages created after the challenge ?)
Should I add any further specification ?

Comment: Do X without Y is discouraged. We're talking about your question in [chat] right now. (And now the conversation's moved on...)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Would removing the "not use characters in the program name" rule make it better ? 

I didn't want the challenge to become "who has the shortest *printf* command"

Comment: At the moment it's "who has the shortest program name".

Comment: If the challenge is in danger of becoming "who has the shortest *printf* command" then rather than trying to fix it you should consider throwing it away and looking for an *interesting* challenge.

Answer (score -2):

## Make a dummy C program

We all know the feeling. You have written a short, efficient and readable one-liner that's the perfect solution to the problem. Then your code-illiterate boss looks over your shoulder and is not very happy that you've spent an entire paid hour producing "nothing". You *could* politely explain the situation to your boss, complete with a demonstration that your code does what it should. Or, because talking to people is Hard Work™, you could fake it.

Your task is to write a program that takes a list of keywords as input, and outputs dummy C code that looks like it does something to do with those words. ***Sandbox note:*** not happy with the wording in final bit here.

For example, if the inputs were `integral`, `formula`, `math`, `proof`, `fit` and `square`, the output might be:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
double* squarefit(int integral, float* mathproof)
{
    char **integralb={{0}};
    double square[integral];
    int i=0;

    //integral math formula fit
    for(integralb[0][0]=(char)erff(*mathproof);isnan((double)++integral);i++) {
        return hypot(sqrt(square[integral]),integral)?square:square;
        printf(*integralb,integral,*mathproof);
    }
    setjmp((struct __jmp_buf_tag*)mathproof+(int)(abs(--integral)-expm1l(integral)));
    longjmp(0,0);
    return square;
}
```

Although it doesn't have to *do* anything, or even run successfully properly, the source code produced by your program must compile in `gcc` (no additional options) without fatal errors. You do not need to provide a `main` function; if you don't, expect the line `int main(void){}` to be appended to the output file before it is compiled.

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the best-liked answer will win. However, voters should keep these questions in mind when assessing the submissions:

- Does the produced source code look like it does the expected task? *Yes.*
- Does the produced source code look like it has taken a long time to produce? *Yes.*
- Do different inputs result in the same program, just with different variable names? *No.*
- Does the produced source code look like the same code repeated over and over? *No.*
- Do your [parents, grand-parents, co-workers or other "not computer people"](//xkcd.com/627/) think the produced source code was something to do with the input keywords (optional)? *Yes.*
- Would *you* think the produced source code was written by a person with knowledge of the C language, if you did not know that it was just dummy code (optional)? *Yes.*
- Does the code look readable (e.g. ungolfed)? *Yes.*

Not all of the standard loopholes apply for this challenge. For example, you mignt use external resources, such as library files or an indexable website. However, voters should use their discretion as to what is reasonable and what is not (such as expecting the "keywords" to be in a format that includes a high-quality, valid C program).

***Sandbox note:*** how to finish challenge body?

Comment: Is this a language-specific challenge?

Comment: @tuskiomi No, it's open to all languages.

Comment: Generally it's a good Idea to separate your challenge into five sections: the *intro*, *summary*, *input*, *output*, and *examples*. I'd recommend you do so here as well.

Comment: @tuskiomi Thanks, will do. Give me 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: @tuskiomi I disagree. There are plenty of ways to organize a challenge effectively. However, this challenge looks like it might suffer a bit from the "art contest" issue, so be wary wizz.

Comment: @HelkaHomba I never said that it's the ONLY way to organize challenges to be effective, I said that generally it's a good idea to do that format.

Comment: @HelkaHomba That's the format I often use, and I plan to split it into headings. What do you mean by "art contest issue"?

Comment: I mean the judging is up to the whim of the voters own opinions and knowledge of how C code should look. We've had issues before with challenges like "draw the prettiest picture" which is plainly an art, not programming contest, and those kind of thing rarely go over well, often close voted as "primarily opinion based". This challenge (and all pop-cons really) suffer from similar issues. I'm not personally against this challenge or art contests, but it's just an issue you may need to face.

Comment: @HelkaHomba Do you have suggestions as to which questions to change / remove / reword to stop it being *bad subjective*?

Comment: I kind of like this, but I bet it would be closed as too broad. Anything from the program you provided to `main(){integral+formula+square+proof+fit==math?return 0:return 1;}` would be allowed.

Comment: @MDXF That wouldn't be valid if the inputs `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `fizz`, `buzz`, `fred` would result in `main(){foo+bar+baz+fizz+buzz==fred?return 0:return 1;}`. Also, `gcc` gets very cross that none of those names are defined, so it won't compile. So actually that wouldn't be allowed. Also note that that is a boring submission to a [tag:popularity-contest].

Answer (score -2):

## The only differences that matter

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

### Cops' task

Write two programs (or functions) A and B in the same version of the same programming language. They also should be called in the same way, meaning you can't write one program and one function. Each should accept an integer *n* and output the term *n* of a different integer sequence on OEIS.

You should reveal a substring of each of A and B. Call them PA and PB. If one instance of PA is replaced by PB from A, it should become B. That means every byte except the reveal part in A and B should be exactly the same. You also reveal the lengths of A and B, and the two OEIS sequences. You don't reveal the programming language you use.

Your answer is cracked if a robber finds two programs A' and B' that also print the elements in the two integer sequences respectively, where A' is no longer than A, and A' with one instance of PA replaced by PB is also B'. They don't have to be the same with your original A and B. And they don't have to be in the same programming language as yours, as long as they are in the same programming language themselves.

If your answer isn't cracked 7 days after you post the answer, you can reveal your language and the original A and B and mark the answer safe, and it will be immune to future crack. Your answer can still be cracked if you don't do it.

Your score is max(len(A)+len(PA)*5, len(B)+len(PB)*5). The safe answer posted before a certain date with the minimum score wins.

For example, if your two programs are `The first program` and `The second program`, you can reveal `first` and `second`. Your score is 18 + 6*5 = 48. And a robber can crack your answer by `<<first>>` `<<second>>` if they work. But you can also reveal `first pro` and `second pro` to prevent this crack.

Please post your answer using this template:

```
# <length of PA> / <length of A> bytes, <length of PB> / <length of B> bytes, score <score>, <open / safe / cracked>

Part of program A (outputing [<OEIS number>](<OEIS link>)):

    <code of PA>

Part of program B (outputing [<OEIS number>](<OEIS link>)):

    <code of PB>

<any other explanations>
```

### Robbers' task

(To do.)

Comment: Do robbers have to produce the same program, or any program?

Comment: There are two tricky edge cases around character encodings which the question needs to address. 1. It talks about substrings of A and B, saying that every byte except the revealed ones must be the same. If A and B differ in one Unicode codepoint, such that in UTF-8 they differ in only one byte but it's part of a three-byte sequence, can I post just that one byte as PA/PB or must I post the three-byte sequence? (I.e. are the substrings operating on the bytes or on the codepoints?)

Comment: 2. If my program is in APL using an 8-bit encoding, do robbers answering in a language other than APL have to have the same bytes in the part of their file corresponding to PA/PB or the same Unicode codepoints?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Any program.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm considering requiring every program to be in printable ASCII (and tabs and newlines), as some special characters effectively banned many languages. But I'm not sure about newlines, which have the \r problem.

Comment: Maybe I'll just say \r\n is counted one byte in this challenge, and is interchangeable with \n. But the programs in one submission must use only \n or only \r\n.

Comment: An example would make this easier to understand,

Comment: I'm skeptical about having the programming language be a free variable. If a cop writes an answer using a verbose language, a robber can comment out all the visible parts and stuff a terse language answer into the cracks.

Comment: @feersum But that's the whole point of all the requirements. If you comment out all the visible parts, both your programs usually should output the same thing. But I realized it's easy to have some workarounds in languages such as Befunge. I may try to find a way to ban them, or just abandon this post.

Answer (score -2):

## Translation Polyglot

Your task is to write a program which runs in two distinct programming languages to translate text.  Input should be translated between each language i.e. running your code in Code Language A translates from language 1 to 2, while running your code in Code Language B translates from language 2 to 1.

**Rules:**

- Code Languages must be distinct, two versions of the same language are disallowed
- Your code may be a full program or function
- Your code must take one string (or nearest equivalent) as input.  Input may be user input, function arguments, or other reasonable form
- Output may be a function return, output to STDOUT, or other reasonable form.  I do not care about trailing newlines or spaces
- Your code may translate from/to any language on the [official language list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_official_languages). List the languages in your answer
- To accomplish your goal, you may use prebuilt language tanslation dictionaries such as the ones found [here](http://www.june29.com/idp/IDPfiles.html).
- If you read your dictionary as an external file, only the code to read in the file (`f = open("dictionary.txt", 'r')` in Python) counts towards your byte count. If your dictionary is hardcoded in, only count the bytes required to make it syntatically valid code (`s="word1_in_english word1_in_french ..."` would be 4 (`s=""`)). Essentially, do not include the dictionary as part of your submissions byte count.
- The dictionary you use **must** have been created before this post (including sandbox time). You may not modifiy the dictionary in any way.
- Any built-in translation tools are disallowed. Built-in dictionaries are ok, but whatever code used to import them into your code must be included in the byte count

This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: wait... Are you actually asking for machine translation? Seems very difficult. Haven't you ever seen bad translator? If it actually is machine translation, this won't work, because of the different resolution of the languages (like converting a jpg to a png and expecting the same quality back)

Comment: It's really just value lookup. I'm not asking people to to make their own dictionary, just use a pre-built and accept whatever it translates

Comment: But that doesn't really satisfy `Language A produces output O from input I, while running in Language B produces output I from input O.`

Comment: Ah, now I see the source of confusion. Updated text to require basic translation, not symmetric translation

Comment: Also I don't think translation is objective enough for code golf...

Answer (score -2):

## Urinal Discomfort!

This question springboards off of [Positional Bathroom Etiquette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98129/positional-bathroom-etiquette), while adding an extra twist.

#### Background

I'm going to take @Nick Frev 's formulae for the total discomfort of a urinal spot

```
dist(x,y) = linear distance between person x and person y in Urinal Units
discomfort(x) = sum(1/(dist(x,y)*dist(x,y))) for all persons y excluding person x
total_Discomfort = sum(discomfort(x)) for all x
short_urinal_discomfort = discomfort_from_surroundings + 1/9 (inherent_discomfort)
```

Your task is to put a person into the spot with the least total discomfort. However, now you have big and small urinals. The small ones, obviously, cause a little inherent discomfort, so we prefer to not use those if we have a choice.

### The Challenge

#### Input/Output

Your program will take in a string of `1,0,i,o` to represent the row of urinals. `1` represents a person in a tall urinal, `0` is an empty tall urinal, `i` is a full short urinal, and `o` is an empty short urinal.

Using the above formulae, build a program that will replace an empty urinal with the correct placement of the next person(`0->1` or `o->i`).

- The short urinals have an inherent discomfort of `1/9` which will be added onto the discomfort provided by the surroundings.
- The door is to the right of the row, so the urinals fill up right to left, because you have to pee really bad and can't walk further than you have to.

> `Input      Output
>   000          001
>   101          111
>   1000001      1001001
>   101010101    101010111
>   000o         001o
>   100o         100i
>   oo0oooo      oo1oooo
>   11000ii      11010ii`

### Any tips would be super helpful

More test cases maybe?
Or more clarification?

Answer (score -2):

## Stump the OEIS!

The [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) is a wonderful database of integer sequences, but occasionally, there are code golf problems that generate integer sequences not found in the OEIS.  Your challenge is to write some code that generates a sequence that meets all of the following criteria:

1. Sequence must not exist in the OEIS.  Prove this by providing a link to the search for your sequence showing 0 results, such as this: [1,2,6,81,35246](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C81%2C35246&language=english&go=Search).  In the spirit of good faith, please do not generate a sequence that is merely an existing sequence offset or multiplied by some constant.
2. The sequence must be non-repeating, non-oscillating, etc.  Formally, there must not exist a subsequence `S` with finite length `L`, that begins at index `I` such that the subsequence from `[I+kL]` to `[I+(k+1)L-1]` for every `k` is identical to `S`.  Such an invalid sequence would be `0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...` because the subsequence `1, 2, 3` beginning at index `1` with length `3` also exists as the subsequence from `4` to `6`, from `7` to `9`, from `10` to `12`, etc.
3. The sequence must contain a minimum of 3 distinct integers.
4. The sequence must be deterministic, e.g. there must not be any element of randomness in the generation of your sequence.  Every time your program is run, it must provide the same exact sequence.

Please write code that provides as many integers in your sequence as feasible.  At least 20 is recommended, though sequences that grow incredibly fast can provide fewer, provided you also give a proof that your code *would* produce that number if given enough time.

This will be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) problem, so the entry with the fewest number of bytes wins.

A bonus of `-20%` can be applied to your score if, in addition to your sequence, you can also provide some mathematical justification for your sequence being included in the OEIS in the future.

Standard loopholes are disallowed, as well as sequences that are simply "this sequence is just the handful of numbers I came up with to fit this problem."

Comment: You say "must contain an infinite number of entries not 0 or 1", then go on to talk about finite sequences, so I'm not sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: Changed it to "The sequence, if infinite, must contain" blah blah blah

Comment: This is definitely going to be closed as "Too broad" - if it isn't closed first as "Unclear what you're asking" because of the impossibility of testing whether "*this sequence is just the handful of numbers I came up with to fit this problem*."

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I removed the possibility of finite sequences, then IMO that second possibility goes away.  As for being closed for too broad, there have been problems that don't have a single goal that have done well, such as [Does this code terminate?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97004/does-the-code-terminate) that inspired a lot of very creative answers.

Comment: Its pretty easy to fill most of the requirements you've listed here:  all you need to do is combine two different OEIS sequences (multiply or add).  Restriction 3 should be changed to "Your sequence must contain at least 3 distinct terms".  I'd also *definitely* recommend disallowing finite sequences, as well as the 20% bonus (which is very ambiguous)

Comment: @NathanMerrill That's a good idea for a change to #3, but as for being able to simply combine existing sequences, there's [plenty of](http://oeis.org/A023607) [existing sequences](http://oeis.org/A081659) like that are already in the OEIS even without necessarily being important.

Comment: @GabrielBenamy right, its not necessarily a bad thing, its just that most sequences generated aren't going to be that interesting.  Also, what's to stop me from simply adding a random "9" number to the beginning of the sequence, or replacing the first term with "9"?

Comment: Consider the family of sequences parameterised by `x` where `S(x, n) = n >= x ? n+1 : n`. Only a finite number of those sequences are either in OEIS or a linear transform of a sequence in OEIS. Are they caught by "*just the handful of numbers I came up with to fit this problem*"? IMO it's ambiguous.

Comment: That's a good point.  Is there any way to salvage this concept?

Comment: This is similar to the question "print something with no results on google". It got closed for being a question about Google's database, not about code-golf, so this one will probably be closed too.

Answer (score -2):

## Golf + Polyglot + Circle = ?

In [the original challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99674/make-three-polyglots-that-make-each-other-and-golf-two-of-them), we asked you to do this:

```
Program | Language | Result
--------|----------|----------
A       | A        | Program B
B       | B        | Program A
A       | B        | Program C
B       | A        | Program C
C       | A        | "Wrong language!" 
C       | B        | "Wrong language!"
```

Now we're asking you to do this*:

```
Program | Language | Result
--------|----------|----------
1       | 1        | Program 2
2       | 2        | Program 3
3       | 3        | Program 4
        |    ...   |
X       | X        | Program 1
--------|----------|----------          
1       | Any but 1| Any member of Set %
2       | Any but 2| Any member of Set %
        |    ...   |
X       | Any but X| Any member of Set %
------------------------------
Set %   | Any lang | "Wrong language!"
```

[(see original challenge for clarification)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99674/make-three-polyglots-that-make-each-other-and-golf-two-of-them)

### Rules

- Do not grab source off of internet, or read own code from file
- Programs don't have to be distinct - you can make a polyglot quine
- Don't take input for any of the programs
- Different versions of the same language count do as different languages. (although this is discouraged because it leads to boring solutions)
- Standard loopholes apply

### Scoring

Score is `byte_count_of_program_one/2.75**languages_supported`, the submission with the lowest score wins.

### Template

Because of its length, [the answer template is here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/3378b47affe73e1825ff4cb179a83e17).

---

<sub>*not that I'm expecting X to be so large</sub>

Comment: +1 this comment if you think the title should be "Polyglot-Quine-Codegolf Returns!"

Comment: +1 this comment if you think the title should stay the same

Comment: Reply to this question if you have a better title

Comment: I personally think the title is way too descriptive, but "polyglot-quine-codegolf" isn't really descriptive enough. The problem is, I don't currently have a better idea...

Answer (score -2):

## Signs in Permutations

#### Introduction

Let's take the permutations of `123`.

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

We can insert signs in between the numbers and count how many `>` signs there are:

```
1 < 2 < 3 # 0
1 < 3 > 2 # 1
2 > 1 < 3 # 1
2 < 3 > 1 # 1
3 > 1 < 2 # 1
3 > 2 > 1 # 2
```

We can arrange this in a table with `n` corresponding to the number (in this case `3`) and `k` corresponding to the number of `>` signs, you get this:

```
┌───┬───┬────┬─────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│n\k│ 0 │  1 │  2  │  3  │  4 │ 5 │
├───┼───┼────┼─────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│ 1 │ 1 │    │     │     │    │   │
│ 2 │ 1 │  1 │     │     │    │   │
│ 3 │ 1 │  4 │   1 │     │    │   │
│ 4 │ 1 │ 11 │  11 │   1 │    │   │
│ 5 | 1 │ 26 │  66 │  26 │  1 │   │
│ 6 │ 1 │ 57 │ 302 │ 302 │ 57 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴────┴─────┴─────┴────┴───┘
```

#### Task

Given an `n` and `k`, print the number in the table corresponding to that `n` and `k`.

Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

[Related OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A008292)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: [Dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96747/194)

Answer (score -2):

I want to post the question here to make sure it is suitable.

## Question: Word Equations

Given a word equation, the solution must output the answer.

My definition of a 'word equation' is an equation where the operators are words.

The operators will be spelt as

add
minus
times 
divide

The solution must take one input

The solution must give one output

#### Examples:

Input: 7 add 8
Output: 15

Input: 9 times -2
Output: -18

Input: 24 divide 2
Output: 12

Input: 4 minus 5
Ouput: -1

You are not required to deal with divide by zero errors.

Fewest characters will win

Feedback is welcomed

Comment: What is the winning criterion?

Comment: @daHugLenny fewest characters, should have known to include that

Comment: Be aware that you will receive many answers in the form: substitute words with corresponding char (+-*/), then evaluate the string you got. Non necessarily a bad thing, just pointing this out in case you expect people to build a calculator from scratch.

Comment: @Leo the way I expected to solve it was by char substituting. However building a calculator from scratch only using + and - could be an interesting challenge

Answer (score -2):

### GoL flooding

Considering a 1000x1000 grid (no wrapping, borders dead), your task is to grow the maximum "stable" population from the fewer individuals.

For the purpose of this challenge, the definition of stable is a configuration who repeat with a period of less than hundred(100) generations.

## Scoring

Your score is lowest number of live cells in your stable population divided by the number of initialy live cells, highest score win

[game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life)

[meta post about on topicness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/are-gol-challenge-on-topic)

Comment: How many generations does the simulation run before the score is tabulated?

Comment: @TimmyD I would say 10.000 but feel free to suggest a better number if you think it could improve

Answer (score -2):

## Convenient Palindromic quine golf, Cops [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

*This is the cops thread, the robber's thread is [here.](http://example.com)*

### Cop's Challenge

A program is *conveniently palindromic* if

> it is equal to the string derived when its reverse has all its parentheses (`()`), brackets (`[]`), and braces (`{}`) flipped. No other characters are special and require flipping. (`<>` are sometimes paired but often not so they are left out.)
>
> <sup>copied from this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/convenient-palindrome-checker).</sup>

Write a conveniently palindromic program that prints its own source. This is the robber's goal:

- Remove byte(s) from the cop's program so that the resulting program:

  - prints the original source, or
  - prints the new modified source
- Resulting program need not be a convenient palindrome

### A counterexample

#### JavaScript

```
(function $(){console.log('('+$+'())')}())//((){('(()'+$+')')gol.elosnoc}()$ niotcnuf)
```

is easily cracked because the robber can remove all the characters past the comment and it will still print its own source.

### Rules

- Program must be longer than one character
- No reading from a file or grabbing from an external resource
- Submissions that aren't cracked for 7 days are marked as "safe", and cannot be cracked anymore
- Cop's submissions after XX/XX/XX are non-competing (can be pushed back depending on popularity), so there are still robbers around to crack it
- The shortest safe solution in bytes wins.
- Robbers won't have a chosen winner

---

Comment: This is basically just a "comment-free palindromic quine" challenge, right? When those challenges have been run elsewhere, the comment-freedom has been verified via brute forcing rather than via a robber, and I suspect that the robbers might not have much to do here. (That said, some languages are slow enough that brute-forcing their correctness would be difficult.) In other news, you should probably require [proper quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4877/62131) rules, even if we can't quite define them; under your current rules, `1` is a valid palindromic quine in PHP.

Comment: I would possibly change the palindrome restriction to [convenient palindromes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28190/42545), as these are way easier to implement in most common languages such as JS and Python.

Comment: @ais523 1. Yas. That was my aim! 2. It's difficult to implement a brute-force solution for a longer submission, how would that work? 3. `Program must be longer than one character` 4. Thanks.

Comment: `11` then :-P. Also, in a way I think this might be more interesting with true palindromes, as it forces you to hide the backwards string somehow, but I agree that it would disqualify a lot of languages.

Comment: @ais523 I'll do a true palindrome one then a convenient palindrome one later, perhaps? (also `11 then` means ?)

Comment: @ais523 `When those challenges have been run elsewhere,` they have?

Comment: Neither [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/comment-free-polyglot) challenge nor [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100520/comment-free-polyglot-with-different-nontrivial-behaviour-per-language) challenge has the same task as yours, but they both disallowed comments in much the same way as this one (i.e. by ensuring that deleting from the program breaks it).

Answer (score -2):

## Prelude:

Joke languages are allowed.
Submissions' scores will vary depending on whether they'll be made in a joke language, golfing language or a Turing complete language, don't worry if your score is high just because you chose a TC language.
That being said, let's get right into the challenge...

## Challenge:

Make a program as close as possible to the language name and document what it does in the description.

## Scoring/rules:

(will assume a simple language I made up, called Printr that has only a `print()` command that can take a argument to print but doesn't have to)

- Submissions that contain more than a 1/2 of whole language name in a string (ex. `print("Printr")`) are banned.
- Submissions must not throw any errors/exceptions/warnings (writing to an error stream is okay though).
- +1 for every char away from language's name (ex. `print("r")` is 4 chars away, `("")`, +4 points)
- Submissions need to contain (at least once) the language name "in a row" excluding nonalphanumeric characters and ignoring case (ex. `print(" *@)!R")` is okay, `print("lolz R")` is not okay)
- Duplicates of the name will be counted as other characters (ex. `print("r") print("r")` is still `4+1 [space]+10=15`).

By looking as close as the language I mean having the least score (since scoring is based on other characters than the language name itself.

## Example:

### Printr, score 4:

`print("r")`

This program prints "r" then quits.

Comment: is it allowed to throw an error?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc, good question, errors shouldn't be allowed (syntax error be like).

Comment: What about a warning to `STDERR`? Stray error output is allowed by default on meta...

Comment: @Flp.Tkc, should be okay.

Comment: `><>`, in ><>, score 0, infinite loops.

Comment: or actually if we're excluding non-alphanumeric characters, this could also be golfed down to `>` or empty depending on if outputting "something smells fishy..." is a valid program.

Comment: in brainfuck you can just write `brainfuck` and it won't do anything...

Answer (score -2):

## Print number of possible values of X if:

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

- Code 1: X is dividable by 3, X contains the number 3 and input() < X < 10000
- Code 2: X is dividable by 7, X contains the number 2, X doesn't contain the number 3 and input() < X < 5000

**Sub-Challenge:**

Do the same but instead of printing the number, print the values

---

Disclaimer: This is my first code golf challenge, and it's very simple, but could bring up some really short answers and cool languages

Comment: First thing: Sub-challenges are not a good idea. People will write the shortest code they can and just disregard the sub-challenge.

Comment: Should you output the sum of the numbers from both two bullet points, in one? I don't think it benefits the challenge to have two different upper limits. I can see why you want it there, but I personally don't think it's a good thing. This needs some good test cases.

Comment: Those were actually different puzzles, sorry!

Comment: Two different independent puzzles in one challenge is not a very good idea either I'm afraid. I think it would be better to use the same upper limit and require the numbers from both 1 and 2 together, I.e. the union of the two sets.

Answer (score -2):

## [please suggest a name]

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)[path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)

Mark got an idea of making a path finding algorithm for auto driving vehicles.

Unfortunately, Mark doesn't yet know about programming, so he decided to
get help from the code golfers.

---

## How should it work?

First, we input how many 'nodes' there are.
we call it 'N', and its an integer up to 16 bit values.

Second, we input what nodes are connected to each nodes, and the length of the connection.
for example, if the diagram is

`(1)-5-(2)-2-(3)`

the input should be

```
2 5  //node 1 is connected to node 2, and the length is 5
1 5 3 2 //node 2 is connected to node 1 and the length is 5. and its also connected to node 3, and its length is 2.
2 2  //node 3 is connected to node 2, and the length is 2.
```

then, finally, the starting node, and the final node.
they are inputted as node numbers.

### Your code should output the path of the shortest way to go from the start to the final node.

## Examples

Input:

```
3
2 5
1 5 3 2
2 2
1 3
```

Output:

`1->2->3`

Explanation:

`(1)-5-(2)-2-(3)`
starts from 1, and ends in 3.
there is only one path, and it is the answer.

---

## Specs

Standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11310/13486). And [another related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153/13486). Suggested tags for this challenge: [tag:graph-theory] and [tag:path-finding]

Comment: Not a duplicate. Though related, clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: By the standards of this site, it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Proof of duplicate?

Comment: Currently the only differences are that not all nodes are necessarily connected and the specified input format. However both input formats are tight and string based, so I'd like to see this challenge with a loosened input format, e.g. allow all reasonable input formats for a weighted graph.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. @Laikoni

Comment: The way we identify duplicates on this site is to ask ["Can answers from one question be copied over to the other with little or no modification and still be competitive?"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules)

Comment: @trich Seems legit, but those two question have quite of a difference, and second, I have came up to this idea all by myself, and being tagged as dupe, seems a tad unfair.

Comment: Being marked as duplicate doesn't mean "This is a bad challenge", it just means "This challenge has already been posted". This is a good challenge idea, but we only host each challenge once, so that all the answers are in one place.

Answer (score -2):

## Generate "N" random numbers which their sum is exactly "N"

Your goal is to generate `N` pseudo-random numbers `R`, then sum or subtract all the `R` togheter and obtain as result `N`.

**Rules:**

- You get `N` from standard input as integer number, such as `N <= 1000`.
- You can't perform operations like sum `100` times `1`, `50` times `2`, or similar...
- `R` shall be generated in any reasonable non-deterministic way
- `R` shall be integer such as `0 <= R <= N`.
- `R` can't have a constant value each time you generate it. For example you can't generate `R` with methods like `R = rand(1,2)` with the result that `1 <= R < 2` (`R` is constantly always `=1`), and then sum `R` 100 times.
- You can perform only sums or subtractions of the generated `R`'s.
- You **have to** sum or subtract the newly generated `R` to the total of `R`'s.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.

**Example 1:**

1. Get `N=100` from standard input.
2. Generate `100` pseudo-random integer numbers `R` such as `0 <= R <= 100`.
3. Sum or subtract all the `R` and obtain `100`(`N`) as result.

**Example 2:**

1. Get `N=20` from standard input.
2. Generate `20` pseudo-random integer numbers `R` such as `0 <= R <= 20`.
3. Sum or subtract all the `R` and obtain `20`(`N`) as result.

**Not-so-smart-but-working example in C#:**

```
using System;           
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int S = 0, N, R = 1, X;
        int INPUT = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int I = 1; I < (INPUT+1); I++) {
            X = (INPUT+1) - I;
            if (I == INPUT && S == INPUT) {
                R = 0;
            }
            N = rnd.Next(R, X);
            if (S <= INPUT) {
                S = S + N;
            } else {
                S = S - N;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("I = {0}      N = {1}     S = {2}", I, N, S);
        }
    }
}
```

[Test online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H8eeR6)

**Tags:** [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is.  If my program accepts the number 20, I have to generate 20 random numbers that sum to 20?  So I generate random real numbers?  Integers?  Positive integers?  Positive-or-zero integers?

Comment: "You get N from standard input as integer" and "N shall be generated in any reasonable non-deterministic way" seem incompatible. If these are referring to two different things, then it would be clearer to not call them both N.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your working definition of "*random number*" is, especially given that the system to be implemented has fewer degrees of freedom than "*random*" numbers. For a question about random numbers to be well specified it should state the distributions to be followed (modulo limitations of PRNGs).

Comment: @GabrielBenamy Yes you understood correctly the challenge. I changed it adding more specs and more details. If you have further doubts please let me know.

Comment: @trichoplax Thanks for your comment. I edited the question to make it more clear with more details and specifications. Please let me know if I can improve it in a better way.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am not sure I get what you mean, probably they are too advanced concepts for me :) Anyway I largely edited the question to make as more clear as possible. If you think it needs to be improved please give me your suggestions on how to make it a more clear and better challenge.

Comment: What about cases where it is impossible to sum/subtract to `R`? For example: `N=5, R=[0,1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: @Emigna if you try my C# example it works for N=5.

Comment: If random distributions are too advanced a concept for you then I think you should abandon the idea of trying to post a question about sums of random variables.

Comment: The explanation is still unclear, and needs work in itself. Separately from that, I recommend example inputs and outputs (literal output rather than explanation). The specification should be unambiguous *before* seeing the examples, and then the examples should come afterwards to confirm correct understanding of the spec. At present I believe the intention is to output an expression containing N integers, each added or subtracted, each in the range [0, N], evaluating to N, and for the integers to be randomly distributed *amongst those that meet these criteria*.

Comment: @trichoplax thanks for your comments and explanations, although the challenge seems clear to me it's obvious that I am missing something that goes beyond my knowledges. I think I will delete the post maybe reviewing it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I got an idea and I posted it here to have feedbacks about it and maybe help or suggestions for improvement, but as I said obviously  I am missing something that I haven't studied. I'll delete the challenge.

Comment: A post always seems clear to the person who wrote it, because they already knew what they meant. That's why the sandbox is so useful - I can't tell if my challenge is really clear until I show it to other people. Being unclear doesn't make it a bad challenge. It just means it needs rewording before it will be ready. Here in the sandbox you don't need to delete. You can simply keep making adjustments and getting feedback until it's ready.

Answer (score -2):

## Make the Shape

This is a wider version of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107598/draw-an-asciirisk) question, so it may not get posted.

Given a single character e.g. `H` or `!` and a sequence of letters e.g. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` you must output the character drawn using the letters in the sequence. If you need more letters, just loop through the sequence again.

## Input

A single character, `c`. You can assume that it will always be one character.

A sequence of charaters `s`. All characters must be printable ASCII letters.

## Output

`c` made up of the letters in `s`

## Examples

Let's say `c = "H"` and `s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. The correct output would be

```
ab   cd
ef   gh
ij   kl
mnopqrs
tuvwxyz
ab   cd
ef   gh
ij   kl
```

`c = "!"` and `s = "hello, world"` outputs

```
he
ll
o,
 w
or

ld
```

## Rules

- Shortest code (in bytes) wins
- Any correct output may be outputted i.e. either one of the example
- `c` must be one character
- Leading/trailing newline is acceptable
- Standard golfing loopholes apply
- Lines must be 2 characters thick
- You must use every letter in `s` at least once to make `c`
- Either a full program or a function, **NO** snippets

Comment: You need definitive rules about the shape and size of each letter or else this will probably be closed as unclear.

Comment: This is similar to another question, that I can't find at the moment. It's about making words from other words, nested `n` times.

Comment: _"Both inputs must be surrounded by `"`"_ - um, why? This isn't a [tag:parsing] challenge. Input should be allowed to be taken in any reasonable format, as is the code-golf standard. You should only break the IO defaults if it is of paramount importance to your challenge, whereas it just looks like a trivial pointless rule here.

Comment: It was to clarify for languages that need `"` at input. I'll change it.

Comment: Also whoever downvoted can you tell me why? I might be able to improve the question

Comment: If you want to limit it to alphabetical characters, you may use my list of ASCII art: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/5-favorite-letters

Comment: Also, Jack, they're probably downvoting because of how open-ended it is. You haven't defined the layout of any of the characters beyond `H!`.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want to reply to someone, tag them - @JackBates

Answer (score -2):

## Why is it buff...........ering?

As the Internet isn't perfect, occasionally the videos we watch start buffering. When this happens, I get very annoyed. As the wait gets longer, I get even more annoyed.

Your task is to write a function or program that waits a random amount of time and then outputs an angry message with the level of anger increasing the longer it waits

## Input

None

## Output

An angry message and the length of the wait

## Examples

Time waited: 5 seconds

Angry message: Never mind!

Time waited: 30 seconds

Message: I hate YouTube!

Time waited: 1 minute

Message: Die computer, die!!!

This code is an example in Python, obviously ungolfed.

```
import time
import random
messages = ["Never mind!","Getting annoyed","I hate YouTube!","Die computer, die!"]
slept = random.randint(5,60)
msg_num = slept//len(messages)
time.sleep(slept)
print("Time waited:",slept)
print(messages[msg_num])
```

## Rules

- Messages are up to you
- The time to wait ranges from 5 seconds to 1 minute
- Standard code-golf rules apply
- Standard code-golf loopholes are disallowed

Comment: This won't work as [tag:code-golf] because it'd mostly be about golfing the angry messages in question, and golfing English is always highly subjective; how angry does the message have to be before it qualifies as "angry"?. I don't really see it working with another victory condition, either.

Answer (score -2):

## Don't know what to call this

Some people here may be familiar with [Euler's identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity). If not click the link

Now you know what the equation is, what if we change it slightly? No-one like to imagine numbers so instead we're going to use an unknown number `x`.

So first we get rid of `i` and replace it with `x`. Now we all know that `i*i` is `-1`. But with `i` gone, so must `-1`. Let's change it to `x^2` instead. However this means there is only one solution. So instead let's make it `x^random_integer(0,x)` to spice it up

If we change the equation from `e^(i*π) - 1 = 0` to `e^π / (x^random_integer(0,x)) = 0` we now have something we can work with.

Given an integer or float as input, `x`, calculate if it satisfies the above equation. Your code should result in `True` or `False` or the closest equivalent.

## Input

A single number between `-(2^32-1)` or what ever your language can handle and `2^32-1` or whatever it can handle called `x`

## Output

A Boolean that says whether the number satisfies the above equation and the random number that is picked

## Rules

• The code must calculate if `x` fits this equation rather than take it from an outside source

• Results in True if within -0.1 and 0.1

• This is code-golf so shortest code (bytes) wins

• Builtins that postdate this challenge are allowed unless they are specifically designed for the sole purpose of winning this challenge

• Standard code-golf loopholes apply

## Examples

```
x = 5
e^π / 5 ^ rand(0,5) = 0
rand(0,5) = 2
results False (0.92)

x = 6
e^π / 6 ^ rand(0,6) = 0
rand(0,6) = 4
results True (0.01)
```

Comment: Most languages don't have accurate enough floats to be able to compare the two sides as equal. As such, they could just arbitrarily return false. You might want to add a precision level. (Also, I assume there are only finitely many solutions anyway…)

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit all over the place. I'm not perfect with the maths and keep changing it so it might work :/

Comment: I found something that works! :)

Comment: Check rules number 2 and the examples

Comment: According to your equation the rule number two has both of those as false, 0.92 and 0.64 are not 0.1 away from 0. Random numbers are also usually considered a bad thing to be using in the challenges.

Comment: Sorry got the example wrong, fixing now. I thought it was to 1 while I did the first one :/

Comment: `e^π / (x^random_integer(0,x)) = 0` requires `e^π = 0` (false) or `x^random_integer(0,x)` to be infinite (in which case it's not strictly true, but it is in the limit). The only way it's going to be infinite with real `x` and non-negative `random_integer(0, x)` is if `x` is infinite. Therefore the explanation of the task effectively states that the task is to return False. It's very confusing that the rules then contradict this.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If you look at rule 2, it explains how to beat this. Also check the example true one

Comment: My point is precisely that rule 2 and the second example contradict the problem statement, which therefore needs fixing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The problem is to find if x satisfies the equation `e^pi / x^rand(0,x) = 0` plus-minus 0.1. Rule 2 and the examples both follow this problem and output the correct result.

Comment: The problem statement clearly says "*Given an integer or float as input, x, calculate if it satisfies the above equation*" where the above equation is `e^π / (x^random_integer(0,x)) = 0`. Then **half a screen later** the rules say, in effect, "*Actually, what I said earlier was a lie.*" That's not the way to write a clear specification. One way to fix it would be to change the problem statement to say "*If we change the equation from `e^(i\*π) - 1 = 0` to `e^π / (x^random_integer(0,x)) = 0` we now have no solutions, so let's make it an inequality: `abs(e^π / (x^random_integer(0,x))) <= 0.1`*".

Comment: What rules make it say "What I said earlier was a lie"?

Comment: Loophole found: Consider `a/(x^b)`: For a non-zero `a`, this fraction gets closer to 0 as `x^b` gets closer to infinity, where higher values for `b` result in outcomes closer to 0. As such, if you want to check if the fraction is smaller than some other value `c` if `b` goes from 0 to `x`, you only have to check if `a/(x^x) < c`, because if that's false, there will be no value for `b` smaller than `x` for which it is true.

Comment: What's your point? Are you suggesting I change it in some way?

Comment: You should at least remove the word "random" from the question, since this has nothing to do with randomness. The question is stated a lot more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: I'll let you decide what to replace it with. 1) A second input, `y` or 2) A constant that is predetermined in the challenge.

Comment: I'd go with a constant, because that's better for golf.

Comment: True but (just playing devils advocate) that leaves a limited number of numbers. A separate variable leaves anything open...

Comment: If you are given a number `x` and a number `y`, you'll have to calculate equation `e^p/x^y<0.1 = x^y > e^p * 10`, and the right-hand side will always be a constant. This always has an outcome (is it smaller or not?), so you're argument doesn't really make much sense (or maybe I don't understand the question).

Comment: Never mind. I just thought it made ads some variety...

Answer (score -2):

## Count My Change

Your task is to sort an array containing the strings "quarter", "dime", "nickel", and "penny" any number of times in no specific order and sort them so that they are in this order: `quarter dime nickel penny` (in other words, greatest to least monetary value).

---

### Rules

1. Your program must take an array as input containing the names of U.S coins and sort them from greatest to least by monetary value.

   - For those who are not from the U.S or don't use change, the values of U.S coins, from greatest to least, are:

     - Quarter: 25 cents
     - Dime: 10 cents
     - Nickel: 5 cents
     - Penny: 1 cent
2. You may sort this array in any way you wish, as long as the output is ordered by the monetary values shown above.
3. Input can be taken in any way, be it command-line arguments or STDIN.
4. An input array would be all lowercase strings, something like this:

   - `quarter dime nickel nickel quarter dime penny penny`
5. If there is a value in input that is not a quarter, dime, nickel, or penny, your program should output `0` .

---

### Test Cases

- `penny nickel dime quarter` should become: `quarter dime nickel penny`
- `nickel penny penny quarter quarter quarter dime dime dime dime`
- `quarter dime nickel nickel quarter dime penny penny`
- `euro quarter nickel dime` would output 0 because a `euro` is not U.S currency.
- esac (not a test case, I just like bash a lot)

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard rules & loopholes apply.

Comment: Test cases please?

Comment: @MistahFiggins On it

Answer (score -2):

A simple challenge: Shortest program that takes the longest to compile.

Comment: What's the scoring requirement (i.e. how will programs be scored)? Who's machine will this be run on?

Comment: It's too broad of a challenge; are infinite loops allowed? To reiterate what Qwerp-Derp said, how will it be scored? Longest to compile -- what if it's an interpreted language?

Comment: @AlexL.: languages without a compiler would be excluded.

Comment: I still believe this is not a good challenge because it is unclear what you are asking and it is too broad.

Answer (score -2):

## What in the heck just happened?

I want you to write a program that will bleep out the H-word, regardless of where it occurs, whether it is inside of another word or a stand-alone word, whether capitalized or not.

### Input and Output

The inputs and outputs of your program may be any of the following: an array of characters, a string, or any other standard data structure which does the job. However, the output must match the case of the input.

### Samples:

```
In the format of Input: Output
A Shell gas station : A Sheck gas station
Hell is a very bad place to be. : Heck is a very bad place to be.
Ella fell and Nelly dug a well. : Ella fell and Nelly dug a well.
Chellsea Thell bought shells. : Checksea Theck bought shecks.
```

Standard loopholes apply, and the entry submitted by [insert date here] with the lowest number of bytes as defined by the Meta will win.

Comment: I can't say for sure, as I don't have an exact reference, but I'm pretty sure a simple find and replace challenge has been done before.

Comment: "Hell" and "heck" are both "H-words", so you need to be clearer. Also, I feel like this is a duplicate. Though these are milder swear words, I think someone did one with swear words in general and it got deleted. If you're going to make a find/replace challenge, it's simple enough to make it about something else.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, are you saying I should change what's being replaced or what my idea is?

Answer (score -2):

## Digitless digits

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)

## Introduction

What we have feared for so long has finally happened, the robots have gained counsciousness and have risen. There has been a war, a global and violent one, and humans have been defeated.

Calcubot, the fearless and tyrannic robot leader, has established a new world order, and its first decree as *Supreme World Leader* has been to forbid all non-AI entities from using numbers.

But, as it's always been the case in oppressive regimes, the Resistance has begun to form. Their first act of rebellion is to print leaflets with numbers on them. However, as the secret robot police is everywhere and can see everything, especially computer programs, these leaflets have to be inconspicuous and must not use numbers within their construction.

## Challenge

The goal of the challenge is to print all digits from `0` to `9` without using them in the source code.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> There is no input required

Output:

> 0123456789

## Restrictions

The source code must not use one of the following characters : `0123456789`.

Also, as this is a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) challenge, your code must be inventive, i.e. please refrain from using prebuilt classes with all the digits or [other standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default). You might still try to make your source code the shortest possible, but not at the expense of inventivity.

The answer with the most upvotes after 7 days will be declared the winner, the time of submission will be used as a tie-breaker.

For example, this is what I had in mind for a PHP solution :

```
$i = (int)false;
foreach(str_split('abcdefghij') as $k) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

## Meta questions

- Has this challenge already been done ? I feel like it's not a revolutionary idea and am afraid someone has thought about it before.
- Could you give me examples of "forbidden loopholes", as I don't really now all the esoteric programmation languages you guys are using.
- Finally, do you think it's a good challenge ? And if not, what could be done to improve it ? That's my first proposed challenge, so I'm aware there might be blatant errors or misses.

Comment: Regarding loopholes, you can link to this: [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: If you intend to ban "boring" answers, like predefined character classes you need to be very careful as writing a [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/47066) challenge can be very hard to get right.

Comment: Code-challenge doesn't provide an objective winning criteria by default so you need to explicitly specify one.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Emigna. I think most upvotes could be the winning criterion, since I don't want it to be a [tag:code-golf] challenge. I'll edit and add the loopholes link.

Comment: Related: [Print all ASCII alphanumeric characters without using them](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105781/62131), [Print every printable ASCII character without using it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90517/62131). This challenge is in between those two, and I'm not sure if there's space for a third (because many answers are likely to end up similar to answer to one of those).

Comment: @ais523 I don't think the second example you're giving could be considered as a dupe, since only one character is forbidden for each execution. As for the first one, I see two major differences with my propose challenge : letters are allowed here, which would make it easier for submitters to create a "real" function, and this is not a [tag:code-golf] challenge, which might reduce the numbers of answers written in esoteric languages such as Brainf**k. I hear what you're saying, but IMO, this challenge could find its space, as I'm really looking for readable and inventive solutions.

Comment: Oh, I missed the victory condition. A "most upvotes" victory condition uses the [tag:popularity-contest] tag, not [tag:code-challenge]. Popularity contests historically tend not to do that well here, as a notable proportion of the site's userbase dislikes them (although many other users are fine with them).

Comment: The winning criterion could be something else, I set it to "most upvotes" because I supposed "The winner is whosever solution I find the most interesting" wouldn't have been a good criterion. I'm open to ideas though, what do you think could be an accurate and impartial victory condition (still, I'd rather not use "shortest code" as the criterion) ?

Comment: "*Inventivity*" is not objective. The obvious way to do this in CJam neither uses prebuilt classes with all the digits nor any other standard loophole, is two characters long, and by virtue of being obvious is probably not "inventive". If you feel the need to try to forbid non-inventive answers, that suggests to me that you already know that the answer to "Is it a good challenge?" is "No, it's not".

Answer (score -2):

### You should log out [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

In the programming language of your choice, log off the currently logged in user.

Rules and clarifications:

- After running the program the user should be taken to the login screen of the appropriate operating system, where they can re-login
- You can assume that no programs are running that would block the logout process with popups
- Solutions that just restart the computer to get to the login page are not allowed
- Always specify which OS / architecture / environment your code runs on
- Standard loopholes are forbidden

This is code-golf, so the lowest amount of bytes wins

---

Sandbox questions:

- I'm unsure how to discourage answers where logout is achieved by expecting the code to be called from bash using "exec", or other solutions where logout is not actually initiated by the program, but by the caller process
- Do we have a tag for architecture dependent questions?

Comment: @LliwTelracs: "After running the program the user should be taken to the login screen of the appropriate operating system", no shutdown will not take you there. Also "Solutions that just restart the computer to get to the login page are not allowed"

Comment: Logout is shutdown with option l. The shutdown challenge was shutdown with option s

Comment: The only difference for linux systems is that the command used will change. All the programs will access the OS commands the same way, which means that all the answers will be portable by changing one piece.

Comment: If you made it prevent me from logging in to PPCG my overall productivity would skyrocket

Comment: That's just a browser extension. Just close any PPCG tabs.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk: There may be a shorter solution on Linux by killing/crashing X (which with some graphical desktop environments, is how logging out is implemented in the first place). I don't think that's enough to make the question substantially different, though.

Comment: bash + utilities, 14 bytes: `pkill -u $USER`

Answer (score -2):

## Google search result short summary

[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) [search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search)

### Intro

When you search in google, it always shows you a result with a sample text from the found webpage.

For example if you search for "Madonna greatest vinyl", google will show you one line link, and below a short excerpt from that found webpage:

**Madonna Greatest Hits Records, LPs, Vinyl and CDs**
*Madonna* - *Greatest* Hits Volume 2, Madonna, Greatest Hits ... *vinyl* Is Fully Restored To As Near New Condition As Possible. Shipping & Multiple Order D..

### Task

Imagine yourself you work for google and you have to write a program/function which takes in:

- a string containing many words (the webpage content)
- list of searched words (at least 3)

and returns the shortest excerpt of given string (webpage) containing all searched words.

#### Example

Given this webpage content:

```
This document describes Session Initiation Protocol (SIP), an application-layer
 control (signaling) protocol for creating, modifying, and terminating
 sessions with one or more participants. These sessions include 
 Internet telephone calls, multimedia distribution, and multimedia conferences.
```

and these searched words:

```
calls, sessions, internet
```

the program should return:

```
sessions include Internet telephone calls
```

, as this is the shortest substring containing all 3 searched words. Note that one more substring contains these 3 words, it is "sessions with one or more participants. These sessions include Internet telephone calls", but it is longer, so it was discarded.

### Rules

- If the string is empty, return empty string
- If all searched words are not found in given string, return empty string
- Search is ignoring letters case
- At least 3 words need to be specified for searching
- The returned string may contain the searched words in different order than specified

#### Challenge

Write the fastest code. It's for google, right? Remember that repeatable strings comparison is very expensive.

Comment: There is not always a short summary.

Comment: Fastest code is going to be tough to measure on this, as even pretty large chunks of text will still result in very small amounts of time.

Comment: You should include more test cases, especially large ones if you want to score by fastest code.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk There is, if all searched words are found in the given string. (For some definitions of short...)

Answer (score -2):

**It's 42!**

This challenge is to code golf a program that proves that the next number in a pattern is 42 based on the website [Actually it's 42](http://www.juanlopes.net/actually42).

In your program, the user inputs a pattern of numbers and it has to output the equation that proves that the next number is 42.

For example, the user inputs the pattern 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 the output is something like:

f(n)=9/2(n^2)−17(n)+29/2

Because f(6) = 42

Your program can output any form of an equation that makes the next value in the equation 42.

Your outputted equation must be able to also output the numbers in the original input also in the form of a variable. For example, in this equation, if you put 1 as the number input you get the number 1.

Your program cannot make any HTTP requests to APIs, in other words, all the calculations must be done in the program.

Good Luck!

Comment: You might want to make your question a bit clearer. Explain input format is first n terms of a sequence. Seems like an interesting idea though

Comment: It seems to me like this challenge is two disjointed parts. 1) is recognizing `the pattern of numbers` and determining the next, and 2) is turning an arbitrary **n** into 42. For 1, you should be clearer about which patterns must be recognized (arithmetic sequences? Geometric sequences? More?), and for 2 you probably need more restriction. For example, what's stopping me from outputting `n - n + 42` regardless of input?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Good point that I have not thought about.

Comment: Making edits to it

Comment: @DJMcMayhem You can't always output `n - n + 42` because it won't fit the previous numbers in the sequence. That is if OP wants the challenge to be to implement the functionality of the linked site.

Comment: However the algorithm used by the site is (according to the [why page](http://www.juanlopes.net/actually42/#why/false/false)) is to solve a system of linear equations, and this has been done before: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22573/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations

Comment: @laikoni Oh, I thought the sequence was the list of inputs, not the list of outputs. I completely misunderstood the challenge.

Comment: Looking at the sole example in the question, the challenge seems to be to output a random function independently of the input. Is this correct? If so, ditch the input. If not, [it's a dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1729/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor the input is required to be taken part in the equation. Hense the rule. You have to output the equation DJMcMayhem

Comment: @Laikoni Well this makes an equation so it does not have to do with that.

Answer (score -2):

## The Mnemonic Major System

People frequently need to memorize long strings of digits, such as
telephone numbers. Fortunately, the [mnemonic major
system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_major_system), which
uses sounds to represent digits, and words to represent strings of
digits, can help.

- **/s/** and **/z/** represent the digit **0**
- **/t/**, **/d/**, **/θ/** and **/ð/** all represent **1**
- **/n/** represents **2**
- **/m/** represents **3**
- **/r/** represents **4**
- **/l/** represents **5**
- **/tʃ/**, **/dʒ/**, **/ʃ/** and **/ʒ/** all represent **6**
- **/k/** and **/ɡ/** represent **7**
- **/f/** and **/v/** represent **8**
- and **/p/** and **/b/** represent the digit **9**
- For the purpose of this challenge, the sound **/ŋ/**, generally
  written as **ng**, counts as **27**.

All other sounds can be used to create words, but do not represent any
digits. Thus, the words **C**o**d**e **G**o**lf**
represent the digits 71 758. Since the mnemonic major system is a
phonetic system, silent letters do not represent any digits. Thus, the
word k**n**igh**t** represents the number 21, not 7271. The
letter **x** is pronounced **/ks/**, and thus represents the digits
70. On the other hand, most double consonants are not actually
pronounced separately (e.g. mummy, chicken), and represent only one
digit.

## Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a string of
digits in any convenient format as input and returns a mnemonic
representation of those digits as output. The following rules must be
observed:

1. You must use real English words. Acronyms and abbreviations are not
   allowed. If in doubt, refer to an authoritative dictionary.
2. Whenever possible, two or more digits must be represented by a
   single word. If the number of digits is odd, you may choose which
   digit, if any, stands alone (see examples). All two-digit numbers can be
   represented by English words.

You may use a built-in or external dictionary to search for suitable words.

This is code golf, so the shortest solution wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
758
golf, kale fee, key leaf

0142710
strengths, suitor nugget saw, seat run key tease

2362185
unimaginatively, gnome gin devil, enmesh native lie
```

Comment: Getting the sounds from a word is not a task that computers can do properly due to the English language not actually following the rules it supposedly has.

Comment: The supplied link to M-W.com is pretty useless. To make a reasonable question you should provide a link to a single file which includes a word list with phonetic representation in easily parseable form. That would also allow verification that the requested task is *possible*, which at present I doubt: are all 1000 possible three-digit groups really representable? E.g. 333 seems like a tough one to represent.

Comment: On a separate issue, the calculation of pi has been done to death, so the interesting part of the question is the mapping from a sequence of digits to a sequence of words. On that basis I would recommend removing pi from the question and instead taking a sequence of digits as input, putting the focus squarely on the interesting part.

Comment: On the dictionary issue, just make the program take the dictionary as an input (and let people use whatever dictionaries they want to *test* their program, given that you could get the answer you want by substituting your own). It's not like hardcoding the dictionary is possibly going to save bytes here, given that even languages with dictionaries built in would have a different dictionary to the one you wanted.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for your input. Whether all three-digit groups are representable is irrelevant for the question as is, since only three three-digit groups need to be represented. However, I think your proposed changes would improve the question. I will do some research on the problem of representing arbitrary three-digit numbers.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Well, English spelling was pretty consistent when it was introduced around 1400. However, written language is generally more conservative than spoken language. While it is difficult to determine how a given word is pronounced, it is not so difficult to construct a word to match a given pronunciation.

Answer (score -2):

## Print the Previous Program

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

#### Specifications:

You must print the exact text of the previous answer without ever having a sequence of more than 5 letters in a row in your program that also show up in the previous answer (prevents hardcoding). Your program must only use UTF-8 characters.

You may repeat a language; however, you may not post twice in a row and no two of your consecutive answers may be from the same language class (different versions are treated as the same language).

#### The first language is to print the exact text "Hello, World!"

0-byte submissions are not allowed.

By the way, this is just a draft, it might be a dupe or really closely related, and probably has more holes in it than Swiss cheese so please give me any suggestions you have. Thanks.

Also, my drafted scoring system is something like `bytes / answer_num` where `answer_num` is which answer yours is (on a time scale).

Comment: "letters" isn't clear, because there are a bunch of Unicode characters that aren't letters. Requiring that no sequence of 5 Unicode characters can be repeated would be better. Additionally, it's traditional in answer chaining challenges for the first program to be provided in the challenge.

Comment: I don't like the 5 letters in a row thing, I think there should be more finegrained restrictions on hardcoding. Additionaly, someone could just do a couple of transformations on program text.

Comment: I'm confused by this "prevents hardcoding" as hard-coding a string is exactly the problem statement.

Comment: @Mego Right, I meant characters. And also, if that's the case, I'll make a program to start off with then. Thanks!

Comment: @Mendeleev That is true. Do you have any suggestions? I'll keep thinking of better ways to restrict that.

Comment: @feersum Not quite, the problem statement is to print out the code of the previous answer without hardcoding it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @feersum How so? The general idea is to generate the previous answer without hardcoding it (because that would be trivial), so it's kinda like a kolmogorov challenge in some sense...

Comment: What does "hardcoding" mean to you? Please give a definition.

Comment: @feersum In my definition, "hardcoding" means that you just put "print" and then the exact text you want printed.

Comment: We usually use "hardcoding" to refer to an answer that exploits a limited input range to avoid performaing an expected algorithm, e.g. for a Fibonacci question where the input is at most 20, writing a list of 20 Fibonacci numbers in the code. Here the task is not associated with any calculation at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55639/discussion-between-hyperneutrino-and-feersum).

Answer (score -2):

## Display Haftseen table items - in Persian/Arabic characters

**Theme** : Jalali New Year 1397

**Main Goal** : Displaying non-ASCII characters correctly

## Introduction

A typical [Haftseen table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haft-Seen) consists 7 items which their names start with `س` (pronounced like *S*) and some additional items. It is set few days before the new year's day and it's kept till end of new year's holiday.

## Challenge

Your program/function should display exactly 7 items from the list below :

```
سبزه
سرکه
سکه
سیب
سنبل
سمنو
سماق
سیر
سنجد
```

with **right alignment**, **right to left typing**, in an **Arabic-compatible font**, with each word **displayed correctly**, and a non-alphabetical character (`,.- =+~?`,newline etc) between each 2 words. The list must be displayed in a window, in terminal or similar.

Comment: I would be surprised if people didn't just output the string directly or with a built-in compression scheme. Say, in Bubblegum.

Comment: @JanDvorak challenge is now changed to *displaying* it instead. i think it's hard enough now.

Comment: Same difference - most environments display the program output rather than ... doing anything else to it.

Comment: @JanDvorak but AFAIK most environment won't display it correctly. do they?

Comment: TIO.run displays it just fine...

Comment: @JanDvorak But it's not right alignment and it's aligned to left

Comment: If that's necessary, my language of choice would most likely be HTML+CSS. I thought you wanted the challenge to be about string compression, though, not choosing the right environment.

Answer (score -2):

## Code - Decode

### Cops:

Your task is to write a program or functon wich otuputs encrypted alphabetic input.
The same program or function has to be used to encrypt and decrypt messages as the case of [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

You have to post in your answer:

1. Languaje and length of your program
2. The encrypted output of the input "CODE GOLF"
3. Two more examples of crypted - unencrypted strings

> Example:
>
> ### Bash, 30 chars
>
> 1. "CODE GOLF" <=> "PBQR TBYS"
> 2. "SHA" <=> "FUN"
> 3. "Why did the chicken cross the road?
>      Gb trg gb gur bgure fvqr!" <=> "Jul qvq gur puvpxra pebff gur ebnq?
>      To get to the other side!"

You may post your program code an decpription of your crypting algorithm once is considered safe.
Shortest uncracked answer wins.

> Example:
>
> `tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'`
>
> This bash command crypts and decrypts messages shifting each letter 13 positions in the alphabet.

### Robbers:

Your task is to write a program or function wich otuputs encrypted alphabetic input.
The same program or function has to be used to encrypt and decrypt messages as the case of [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

Your code has to pass test cases posted on one of the COPS post.
The user who cracks most wins.

**Extra bonus** if your code cracks more than one answer.

[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)[cryptography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)[encryption](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption)

Comment: First cops and robbers challenge, pleas help me writing it nice.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the goal of the robbers to crack the encryption algorithm that the cops create?

Comment: Folowing the example if one cop posts an answer wich uses ROT13 and a robber implements ROT13 the answer is cracked.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/add-randomization-in-cnr-posts-as-a-loophole), which specifically mentions certain types of encryption/decryption

Comment: Certanly I'm not an cryptography expert, wouldn't  the constrait of being the same function that crypts-decrypts avoid such cases of random crypt?
How can I change robber thread to avoud brute force?

Comment: The problem with this is that real encryption is *really* hard to crack.  All they need to do is add a random salt, and the robbers have to blindly guess what the salt is.

Comment: I'm not sure what the proposed constraint is. An encryption function takes two arguments (plaintext and key) and produces one output (ciphertext). Are you saying that for any plaintext and key, `encrypt(encrypt(plaintext, key), key) == plaintext`? If so, I think that's essentially a restriction to stream ciphers, and you might as well ditch the whole plaintext processing and ask for a function which takes the key and the length of the plaintext and generates a deterministic output of that length.

Comment: And it has the same cryptographic flaw that many cops-and-robbers do. It's not even really necessary to use good crypto: something like `for(i='secret';n--;putch(i[0]))i=md5(i);` would require heavy-duty cracking *even if* you hinted that that's the structure.

Comment: ok, i've learned something, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score -2):

## Shortest “Hello World” for common journaled file systems.

Create a valid file system image as small as possible containing a file or a folder labeled “Hello World” with the following constraint:

- If the hello world is a regular file, it needs to not be empty.
- The file system needs to one of the following: **ntfs3.1 ext3/ext4 zfs btrfs hfsplus**

Please note you won’t be able to create the smallest file system with normal fomatting tool.
I mean they don’t allows to create the smallest theoriticall size.

### Winner

The answer with the smallest file system

Comment: Hmm, why not xfs/zfs? Also, I don't really think this is a programming problem

Comment: @ASCII-only the challenge seems to easy with xfs. Otherwise I didn’t got an answer to this question http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36478963#36478963 . Though if it can be made on topic for a code challenge, please explain how. Although it is not a code problem, the special case of journaled filesystem require create a program behind the hood due to the huge number of data structure, so I think it’s still a programming problem, even it’s for being able to only write a unique file.

Comment: You can make it a code problem by changing it to verifying that a byte sequence is a valid ext3 image.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hemmm, by turning it in a code challenge, I still want something that can lead to create very small journaled filesystems. But does programming cahllenges needs also to be code challenges in order to be on topic?

Comment: How are you drawing a distinction between *programming challenges* and *code challenges*? To me they're the same thing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean by handling or creating algorithms you don’t necessarily write code. But anyway this challenge need to be converted into a code challenge while still generating small filesystems. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

## Real Programmers Don't Comment Their Code [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

*(Disclaimer: I do think programmers should comment their code.)*
Your task is to write code in one language that removes comments from code in another language. Both single-line and multi-line comments should be removed from your program. You may write code in one language to remove comments from the same language. Input and output may be in any format. Finally, before answering, read the rules, please.

---

### Rules

1. Your program in language X must take a program in language Y as input and output the code with all comments removed. Language X may be the same as Language Y.
2. You may *not* use language Y if:

   - Language Y has no comments whatsoever.
   - Language Y does not have 2 or more types of comment.
3. Language Y should preferably have unusual comment behavior. (Ex.: older programming languages or Haskell)
4. You may *not* ignore line continuations (usually `\` at the end of the line).
5. Your code may not remove anything inside a string literal.
6. Standard loopholes are disallowed.
7. I strongly encourage you, ironically, to provide an explanation if it is unclear how your code works.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the best programmer with the shortest code win...

Comment: All answers from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/remove-single-line-and-multiline-comments-from-string) apply to this challenge. I'd say this would be a duplicate.

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, it's mostly about selecting a language Y which makes the question as easy as possible. (There are comment markers that are terser to parse than `//…\n` and `/*…*/`, so good answers won't be exactly the same, but they'll still be pretty similar.)

Comment: @ais523 How can I add variation and distinguish my challenge?

Comment: Try requiring a specific Y whose comment behaviour is unusual. A good start would be to pick a language where comments nest, for example, although that might not be enough by itself.

Comment: But Pascal as given in the example only have 1 comment type (start with `(*` or `{`, and end with `*)` or `}`, not in string, and not `(*)`)

Comment: I should make the requirements less strict.

Comment: Done! Requirements less strict.

Comment: "3. Language Y should preferably have unusual comment behavior" very subjective thing, isn't it?

Comment: @officialaimm How to make it less subjective?

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score -2):

## You've been Thunderstruck!

## Background

A "fun" drinking game is based on the classical hard rock song by AC/CD: [Thunderstruck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2AC41dglnM). The Thunderstruck drinking game starts when the song starts. When the word "thunder" is heard, the first person starts drinking, not stopping until the word "thunder" is said again. At that point, the next person begins to drink. This continues around the circle until the song ends.

The "twist" is that in the middle of the song, there is an entire verse where thunder is not uttered once. The person who gets this part -- and thus has to drink for the longest period of time -- is said to have been *thunderstruck*.

## Challenge

*Input:* An Integer number of players.

*Output:* Which player got thunderstruck

## Example

```
Input:  1
Output: 1

Input:  2
Output: 1

Input:  3
Output: 3
```

## Rules

Here are the rules:

- Assume that the number of players always is a positive integer.
- Output should always give a positive integer.
- You are not allowed to hardcode the number of times before the "solo" / long verse. Meaning your code has to find the longest part without the word thunderstruck, on its own.
- [Use the following lyrics for thunderstruck](https://genius.com/Ac-dc-thunderstruck-lyrics)
- Shortest code wins.

Comment: Forbidding hardcoding is not considered an [observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/should-we-disallow-non-observable-requirements).

Comment: You should also state exactly which verse is the one without the thunder (it seems like it is the one after the 16th thunder)

Comment: And I think your 3rd test case is wrong [here](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYWVoplqhkF@kUPE/DUQqZOYpFCXmpadqGOoYGWhaFRRl5pUoVOikaVRo/gcA) is a solution I made in python you can compare it to.

Comment: I think this challenge could be made more fun if you also take a song as input and have to find the longest part without a `thunder`.  This would solve your hardcoding problem and make the challenge a little more fun.

Comment: Just seconding this; this challenge badly needs to take the song as input. If it doesn't, then the problem is that (even banning hardcoding) it becomes mostly about [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] of the song (with the actual finding of the long gap becoming almost irrelevant by comparison), which is both a chameleon challenge and a duplicate; and because it's about kolmogorov complexity, thus compression, it'd be quite easy to choose a compressed representation in which the challenge was easier than you think. (Note that even taking input, the challenge is very easy anyway.)

Answer (score -2):

## Description

Find the number of '1's in a binary number of any length. (Variable name up to you)

## Output

You should output or print an integer/number/string which reflects the number of '1's that were counted.

## Example

`10101100` should return `4`

## Sandbox

I'm new here, so I don't know if this has been asked before. I searched but I could only find one other similar question, however that required the answer to be in binary, and was somewhat different in terms of the inputs.

My question seems very short and lacking details, but I don't know how to expand further on such a simple challenge.

Any other ways I could improve on my first post in this Stack Exchange?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47870/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor but that involves decimal input. This question is for binary input.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that the input will be a string, and the answer has to count the number of times the character '1' appears in it?

Comment: Easy solution: add up all the numbers in the input. Many answers will have one-character answers.

Comment: `O` - 05AB1E and 2SABLE polygot 1 byte.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn c'mon 05AB1E and 2sable are practically the same thing I wouldn't call that polyglot :I

Answer (score -2):

## Add numbers without math functions.

In this challenge, you must take an input that can take at least 10 numbers separated by commas and add them together without addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division symbols. Least bytes win. Normal code golf rules apply.

### Examples:

Input:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Output:

```
55
```

Input:

```
1,1
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: You have to define what a math function is. Are we allowed bitwise operations?

Comment: @BetaDecay Fixed it.

Comment: I'm assuming summation counts as addition because that's just common sense. Does string or list repetition count as multiplication?

Comment: "Do X without math" has no chance of not being closed, just so you know.

Comment: [Probable dup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20996/add-without-addition-or-any-of-the-4-basic-arithmetic-operators)

Answer (score -2):

## Prove the Undecideability of the Halting Problem

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [halting-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem)

[More information on the halting problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111200/7605753)

Either:

Create a program that, when given an input, no single program (which receives your source and your input) can determine if your program terminates, or

Create a function that, when given an input, no single program (which receives your source and your input) can determine if your function returns.

Your score is the byte count of your program plus the byte count of your input (or of the shortest input in the set of input that solves this problem).

Lowest score wins.

//I would love some input on my wording.

Comment: Can I make a request to an external URL until I get a 404?

Comment: @programmer5000 can an external program determine whether your program will halt? For example, by pinging that URL themselves?

Comment: Oh. Could I make a program that stops when it finds 5 points that prove the [Happy Ending Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem) wrong?

Comment: @programmer5000 if your program stops with a given input, and another program can predict that it will stop with that input, your program does not match specs. No input is accepted input, but it is very unlikely that an undecidable program can come from no input AFAIK.

Comment: @programmer5000 from the Wikipedia page it seems like that problem is already solved, so that program will terminate, so another program could predict that. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Um. `eval`. It's one byte long in GolfScript.

Comment: @PeterTaylor you need to provide an input that is undecidable, and that counts towards your score.

Comment: I don't think this is how the halting problem works...

Comment: @DestructibleLemon You may be right; Wikipedia says `a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist`. Do I need to require two inputs? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1111200/7605753) seems to contradict Wikipedia though.

Comment: hmmm, you definitely could do this (make it an interpreter) but I'm not sure how much you have to do to make this work... as in what the simplest program would be

Comment: @StephenS It doesn't require 2 inputs, it requires a pair (program, input).

Comment: It's the *problem* which is undecidable, not the *instances*. If you want to ask for a program which cannot be proven to halt or not halt, you have to specify the axiom system which can be used for the proof. See e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79470/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79620/194

Answer (score -2):

## The 2017 Loader contest

Here's a thing: Let's do the bignum bakeoff again.

Because why not.

#### What to do

Write a program in less than 256 characters that outputs the biggest number you can.
Yep, that's it.  Biggest return value wins.

We'll run the program on a VM with infinite memory. *(How do we do this?)*

#### Rules

- 256 chars max, excluding whitespace
- Different leagues for each language
- Output however you want

  - No explicitly printing numbers until your loop runs out. Print the number you generate directly. <sup>{1}</sup>
- Program must terminate
- No implementation-dependent shenanigans.
- Implementation-independent shenanigans is *encouraged*.
- ints are infinite.
- Program must return the same number every time
- Submission must include the approximate return value in any suitable googological notation.
- Whitespace is space, tab, newline, formfeed, and return

  - *BrainF***: Whitespace is all non-`[]+-<>` characters*

---

**{1}** Allowed ways to return: `printf("%d", num);` `return num;`, etc.
Banned ways to return: `for(;num>0;num--)printf("99999");`, etc.

---

#### This is not a dupe of...

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable) because you can put any characters you want, not just non-digits; because we're hard-limiting the characters.

---

#### Suggested rules

- No floats: `float` `double` `long double`, etc
- No strings or chars
- No bitfeilds
- No looking at Command-line args

Next year's contest will be named after this year's winner, for no particular reason.

http://djm.cc/bignum-rules-posted.txt

---

#### Sandbox

- How do you even test these programs?
- What other rules should we have?

Comment: You don't actually explain the rules of the challenge, we would have to go to that link to find out what we are supposed to do. Aside from that, I think this has a lot of problems with your typing restrictions if these are not limited to C, but limiting it to C wouldn't really fit the spirit of the site. I think you may want to rethink how you want to approach this question.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman "Typing restrictions"? (Added proper instructions)

Comment: Your post doesn't describe how people win. Is it by the largest possible number? Anyway, the problems are things like not counting whitespace, which can easily result in degenerate answers, as well as things like I/O streams and whatnot. All of your extra rules seem entirely based around C with no regard for other languages, which will not go well.

Comment: In answer to "*Because why not*": because it will be [closed as a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/194).

Comment: Here's a couple of rules I would consider.  1. Program must generate the same result every time (e.g. not based on timer, probability, or the like).  2. Submissions should include, if not the exact resulting number, at least a best estimate, in scientific notation if need be.

Comment: Scientific notation? People will post answers that far, _far_ exceed that. In fact, Mathematica, 22: `Fold[Power,2~Range~9999]` It's 2^3^4^...^9999. That's not being represented anytime soon.

Comment: This is a duplicate, and is also going to come down a lot to whether or not you allow programs that exceed the computational capacity of any existing computer. (If you require programs to work on a physical computer, the best they can possibly do is to use the entirety of memory as a counter and print out 9s over and over again. If you don't, the answers can easily be large enough that you need to use notation invented specifically for describing the number, because all other notations are not enough.)

Comment: If your code can [simulate a Turing machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777582/509868), it becomes hard to judge who the winner is, and whether an answer is valid at all.

Comment: Re your latest edit: you're wrong. The question it's a dupe of also has a hard limit to the number of characters; in fact it's a harder one, but the best answers could be copied with slight tweaking to take advantage of the extra space. And the digit restriction turned out not to be a serious problem: the winning answer would gain extremely little from being able to use digits.

Comment: #PHP 8.3 256char
echo exp(bindec("11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"));

Comment: @PeterTaylor That question is closed but I would like credit for my answer.

Answer (score -2):

## Google Logo in Conway's Game of Life

[Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) base challenges are always fun so here is a new one.

This is Google's Logo (if you have not somehow seen it):
[image: Google Logo]

The font is called [Product Sans](https://storage.googleapis.com/g-design/static/product-sans-specimen.pdf). Your job is to replicate this logo (no color of course) in 800x439px just like the image (just the letters).

Have fun! This is a popularity contest so the most votes wins. :D Good luck. Of course, this may not be possible but, you never know until you try.

Usual rules apply.

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life).

Comment: "looks like" isn't a tight enough specification for a challenge.

Comment: Also consider some method besides first-past-the-post, that winning criteria doesn't really work well with this site.

Comment: So the answer could replicate it at the 0th generation?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Popularity contest?

Comment: @Mego Also good point

Comment: OK I updated stuff maybe it will make this challenge better

Comment: 1. I don't see how the change you've made addresses my previous point. 2. Pop-con is barely any better than fastest-gun-in-the-west. 3. It's possible to test whether this is possible or not (I highly doubt it) by [running the CA backwards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10592/194).

Answer (score -2):

## Draw an XBox

Here's an X:

```
\  /
 \/
 /\
/  \
```

And here's a Box:

```
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
+----+
```

So, for an XBox, just draw an X in a Box:

```
+----+
|\  /|
| \/ |
| /\ |
|/  \|
+----+
```

Your input will be a number (in any standard way) that will represent the size of the box. To output the above box, this could be the number of `-/|\`s (4), or the number of lines/columns (6), or even the intercept of the second diagonal (5) would be acceptable. (Don't ask me to accept the base256 encoding of the output though, as that's one of the many banned standard loopholes.)

Your program or function should then output (in any standard way) the XBox of the given size. If the `\/`s cross in the same character, place an X (as per [Draw a big slash X](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125383/draw-a-big-slash-x)). For example, here's an XBox three sizes larger than the one above:

```
+-------+
|\     /|
| \   / |
|  \ /  |
|   X   |
|  / \  |
| /   \ |
|/     \|
+-------+
```

This is [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program wins!

Comment: `in some obvious way` unclear/subjective

Comment: @MDXF 4 examples weren't sufficient?

Comment: I'm just warning you that it could get closed for being too broad due to that statement.

Comment: I agree with @MDXF

Comment: @BetaDecay That's all very well, but I'm unclear as to what you want.

Comment: Just a basic explanation of how scaling works. Some examples would suffice

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @MDXF Here's my problem. I just tried implementing this in Charcoal, and came up with [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69CsIwFIV3nyJkSjAF69hu4iIYEXEQxKG2tzWQJiU/FRHfyKfwxWIrFUR0u/B955ybnzKT60yGsFCNdytfH8GQiqYj7qUTjRHKkWSuz2oJpWNoK2qwZC5aUQCpGJpShvAO06/A487Qp/S3b5C4UN72akwHff0y8Rh3tygR4brwUg9taAOlhNxxYYw2ZN/tHSgCaQFd32zmnQNTygtJ@ima/gD9Hx24hRBPQtSGyMon "Charcoal – Try It Online"). As it turns out, to produce those example XBoxes I actually need sizes of 7 and 10, but I didn't want to penalise that choice of input just because I hadn't predicted that particular scaling.

Comment: @BetaDecay If you still have any further input it would be appreciated.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91068/creating-a-crossed-square)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ugh, I even have an answer on that question... I guess the use of specific characters doesn't really sufficiently distinguish this one.

Comment: @Neil Well, using ``/+x\`` instead of just `*` does make it a bit trickier, but it's indeed a bit too similar imho.

Answer (score -2):

## Print a Variable's Memory Address [suggestions-needed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions-needed)

Similar to [this puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126326/print-a-variables-name) I posted earlier, with a difference that should make this challenge easier.

Create a function (not a full program) that prints or returns the memory address of the parameter passed in. Literal values should return a falsey value.

**Examples:**

```
var foo = 4901
var bar = "foobarbaz"
var baz = true

getMemoryAddress(from: foo) // 0x00000000004030f0
getMemoryAddress(from: bar) // 0x00000000004030f8
getMemoryAddress(from: baz) // 0x0000000000403110
getMemoryAddress(from: "Bad Value") // false
```

Note that you probably won't get the same exact result as show above.

Comment: Example(s) please.

Comment: @Shaggy Updated.

Answer (score -2):

## Migrate questions to and from the Sandbox! [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api)

## Challenge

Write user scripts that will migrate challenges to and from the Sandbox.

## Criteria

These are my suggestions for criteria that will create the most beautiful user scripts. Feel free to suggest your own!

#### Migrating to the Sandbox

The script should...

- only act on a question that has been closed for "unclear what you're asking"
- answer the Sandbox as the original author of the question
- make the title and tags the first line of the answer as a H1-sized header
- link the original question to the Sandbox post, and then delete it

#### Migrating from the Sandbox

The script should...

- use the first line to determine the title and tags for the post, and eliminate it from the post body

  - error handling here would be a good idea
- create the question as the author of the Sandbox answer
- comment on the question with a link to the Sandbox answer
- replace the Sandbox answer with *just* the title and link to the question, then delete the Sandbox answer

## Scoring

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the highest net of votes will win.

## Sandbox

- Is what I'm asking for even possible? I've never written a user script before. Maybe it should be a [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) question?
- Should this be a Community effort rather than a challenge? Does it even belong on main?

Comment: This is not within the capabilities of a userscript. Also, automating this wouldn't really help at all, since the sandbox only does anything if the poster wants to use it. Anyway, if you disagree with me and still want to pursue this, it should be a question on meta, asking if people want a sandbox migration bot.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for your feedback! I've [asked on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13004/a-sandbox-migration-bot) as you suggested.

Answer (score -2):

**Grep for math in a pdf document**

This challenge is likely to need the use of libraries. You may use any free library of your choice as well as any library.

The challenge is simply to write a tool that can grep for "2^n" in a pdf document. That is the math that represents 2 to the power n.  You may assume that the pdf was produced from LaTeX which contains `$2^n$` and that the pdfr was made using the command  line tool pdflatex.

**What should the code do?**

The  code should take a pdf file as input either by reading a file or from standard in.   It should output if the file contains "2^n" or not.

**Scoring**

I will provide a number of pdf files as test examples. Your score will just be how many your code gets right.

**Requests for help**

I could provide sample pdf documents that  do or do not contain 2^n in them.

Does it always appear as an image in the pdf as Mego suggests? If so, this image will depend on the font and font size and this is an image processing task.

Comment: 1. How are you going to score this? Code golf? Popularity contest? 2. PDFs can vary wildly in how something is displayed. If you're specifying that it's produced from a specific program in a specific way, then it's likely just a search for a static string of bytes, which is IMO a boring challenge. 3. What exactly is the output? Is it a simple yes/no, or is it supposed to be location within the file?

Comment: @Shelvacu I was going to score by how often the code gives the right answer.  I would ideally like the code to output the first page number it finds `2^n` on but I don't know if that is too hard. If it is then the output is just yes/no.

Comment: So [tag:test-battery].

Answer (score -2):

## Is it `cat`-urday?

[Caturday](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/caturday) is one of the oldest memes out there. For this challenge you need to write a program that outputs the input, but only on Saturday.

### The catch:

You can acquire the date via UNIX timestamp, or as a formatted date string (local or UTC). **However**, you can not:

- use day of the week information in a date string
- directly acquire the day of the week of a date by some other means
- use Date or Calendar functions, beyond one to simply give you the current date
- use any external resources  (files, Internet)

Don't forget leap years!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Does this question work as is? Should I make anything clearer?

Comment: This is a "do X without Y" challenges, and those have been done to death.

Answer (score -2):

## Output the infinite sequence of middle positions of odd square numbers [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

As everyone knows, every odd square number has an element at its central position — I represent those central elements as an *:

```
n=1 => 1
*

n=9 => 5
###
#*#
###

n=25 => 13
#####
#####
##*##
#####
#####

n=49 => 25
#######
#######
#######
###*###
#######
#######
#######
```

The challenge consists on output the sequence `1, 5, 13, 25, ...` uninterruptedly. The separator does not need to be a comma, but use the same separator always.

There will not be any accepted answer, except if I see some very creative answer. There will be a winner for each language (I will steal Leader board code somewhere)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Comment: Is this equivalent to "output (N+1)/2 for every odd square number N"?

Comment: @trichoplax: Yes.

Comment: `There will not be any accepted answer, except if I see some very creative answer` The whole point of [tag:code-golf] is the shortest answer wins. Why output constantly and not return the Nth or first N terms?

Comment: Also surely this boils down to `for(i=1;;i+=2)Output((i**2+1)/2+",")` which isn't that exciting.

Answer (score -2):

## Hello, Quine! [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world)[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

Your task is to write a program which, if given an input of "Hello," will output "Hello, world!", if given any other input, it will output its source code.

---

### Rules

- Input does not have to be case-sensitive.
- Your program may *not* contain the string "Hello, world!" or any variation with different cases of letters (i.e "hELLO, WORLD!", "HeLlO, WoRlD!", and "hello, world!").
- No "cheating quines."
- Standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden*.

---

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: This is combining two different challenges into one, and I don't see a good reason to do so. (Output your source, and output Hello, World! without it in your source). Also, [tag:restricted-source].

Comment: @StepHen How could I distinguish it somewhat?

Comment: Distinguish it from what? It's just combing two already used challenges - `Hello, World!` without important characters, and quining, into one.

Comment: @StepHen Definitely true.

Answer (score -2):

## Complicating Simple Maths [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

We do know what 1 + 1 is, or 2 - 1. How about we turn those and other really simple operations into complex numbers?

### Goal:

As stated in the intro, taking an operation that can be done within the range of the following operators ( +, -, /, *, ^ and () ), print out a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) operation that is pretty much a transformed version, and when done using the order of operations, results in the same answer as the inputted operation.

### Examples:

```
Input: 5 - 1
Output: 5 + 2i

Input: 4 * (7 ^ 2)
Output: (4 * 4i) * (7 ^ 2)
```

### Rules:

- It is recommended you print out the sector(s) that holds your complex number(s) as a + bi, e.g. (a + bi) - (ci * (di ^ f)). (**NOTE:** If you are doing non-communicative operations, such as ^, /, or -, the recommendation doesn't apply to the sub-operation).
- No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- If you want to, feel free to use operations/functions other than the set mentioned in the Goal, but your input operation must have at least one of them.
- You can format your operators in any way, e.g. x or • instead of *, ÷ instead of /, etc.
- Input and output is allowed in any format as long as it fits within the [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- Input must also be flexible (as in to return any input from a simple operation to a complex number operation.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

### Sandbox use only:

Is there any way I can improve this challenge? Are there any other loopholes to be covered in the rules?

Comment: Can you relax output to standard IO too? At the moment it seems you can only print the result. Also isn't this essentially calculate the result of the inputted expression then work out a complex expression that gives the same answer seeing as you don't need to keep anything in the input the same.

Comment: And if that is the case isn't this challenge just `return input + (1 +
 i^2)`?

Comment: No, the challenge is to transform parts of the input into complex numbers and output that.

Comment: But `5 - 1` becomes `5 + 2i` You are removing two stages `-` and `1` and adding 2 `+` and `2i`. It's not entirely clear how much you can remove and how much you can add.

Comment: At least one sub-operation should be transformed from simple to complex (which could take two steps).

Answer (score -2):

## The Self-Referential Algorithm

Most people are familiar with Tupper's self-referential formula. When the formula is graphed on a calculator it *magically* graphs itself. Wouldn't it be interesting if we could do something similar with a programming language?

### Your task

Write a small program that will be able to output exactly itself when ran.

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with the fewest bytes winning.

Comment: This is called a quine, and is [one of the oldest questions on the site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/194).

Answer (score -2):

## Pascal's Particulars

Pascal is feeling very particular today. He wants to get an element from his famous triangle without going through the work of generating all the prior elements. He'll provide you with a row number and an entry number and you'll provide him with the element at that location.

Example:
Input row = 1, entry = 1, output 1. (row 1 is **1**)
Input row = 3, entry = 2, output 2.  (row 3 is 1-**2**-1)
Input row = 6, entry = 3, output 10. (row 6 is 1-5-**10**-10-5-1)

### Rules

- You will only be provided valid inputs (i.e. x will never be higher than n).
- Your code should either print or return the output value, either works.
- Standard golfing rules apply (lowest byte-count wins, etc.).

Happy golfing!

Comment: you know that you are just asking for binomial(n,k), don't you? this is trivial

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1744/194)

Answer (score -2):

## Break this block

Your challenge is to break this block.
[image: floating diamond]

But of course that would be a pretty easy challenge, that's why this is a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.
The robber's challenge: Break the block. As breaking qualifies everything that has the result that no diamond block is at the coordinates 0 128 0 (even pushing it with a piston) and that follows the rules (see below).
The cop's challenge: Prevent the robbers from breaking the block. As preventing the breaking counts everything that guarantees that there is a diamond block at 0 128 0 in every future game tick despite the robber attempting his solution (and also if he doesn't). You are not in the world while the robber makes his attempt, so you have to prepare the world for him.

### Rules

- You may not use modded Minecraft or external tools that change the save file. Reading it with external tools is allowed.
- You have to show a reproducible way to break/secure the block. Just uploading a world save without saying what you changed is invalid. You should offer a detailed explanation and preferably more (video, screenshots, structure file, etc.), if necessary.
- This challenge starts with a normal world (default generation, Creative+cheats, random seed), where one diamond block was placed using the command
  `/setblock 0 128 0 diamond_block`
  The spawn chunks can include 0 0, but they don't have to. Since both sides have access to commands, that shouldn't matter anyway.

### Sandbox questions

- How should I restrict the version? Should it be "latest release", "any stable release", "only 1.12.1", "any snapshot, release or historical version" or something else? People could come up with interesting solutions using past versions (maybe even past snapshots that aren't selectable in the launcher anymore), but I have to somewhat restrict it. If a certain downgrade automatically breaks the block, it's of course boring, especially since they instantly win. And if they load the world in any of the 9 oldest versions in the launcher (called "Classic" and "pre-Classic), there isn't even a diamond block in the game, so it would be deleted.
- Should I discourage people from instantly preventing every single breaking method with their first "cops" post? To have an interesting challenge, it should slowly become more difficult. If I should discourage it, how to "enforce" it?
- What other rules do I need?
- I'm planning to be very active myself on the "cops" side (I already have some nice ideas), possibly creating the majority of posts there. Is there a problem with that? If no, would it be considered unfair or boring to ask the others to wait up to a day with their solutions? Of course they don't have to do it, I just originally planned this to create programming challenges for myself.
- If every answer on one side can have multiple answers on the other side, which itself could have answers on the first side and so on, that could lead to a tree-like structure. But such a structure would lead to many unanswered questions (if it doesn't keep growing exponentially, what I highly doubt). Is there a way to prevent that or should I even try it?
- Apparently this is the first Minecraft-only programming challenge here. Should a [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag be created for it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What are the submissions? Minecraft commands? A set of instructions? A program that reads a save file and outputs a new one?

Comment: Submissions would mostly be Minecraft commands, but maybe in the first few rounds instructions.

Answer (score -2):

## The Compressor

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

You are given this list of 100 positive integers that are at between 7 and 18 digits long:

[list to come]

You need to generate 100 snippets that will produce these numbers in some language (either as a numeric or string). Your score is the total length of the snippets. Lowest score overall wins, but you should also try to get the lowest score in whichever language your snippets are in. Please include both your snippets and any code you used to generate them in your submission. Note: the generating code isn't actually scored.

### Rules

- The snippets must all be in one language, however it does not need to be the same language as the generating program(s).
- You may assume that any pre-existing libraries you use are already imported.
- You don't need to include the line terminator (i.e ';' in Java and others) for snippets that fit on one line. For multi-line snippets, you don't need to put a terminator on the last line.

### Examples

- `1357000` => `1357e3` (many languages)
- `1234567` => `1234567` (most languages)
- `307422089600` => `S6*99b` (CJam, returns value of [32,32,32,32,32,32] in base 99)
- `12582912` => `12<<20` (JS + others)

---

#### Alternative: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I generated this 100 digit random number with [random.org](https://www.random.org/integers/):

```
7160708104901559695507628057638725214364226867212714872539720713967912042100814603497742352846014272
```

Write the shortest possible program that outputs this number.

---

Related: [No strings (or numbers) attached](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/no-strings-or-numbers-attached)

Questions? Clarifications?

Comment: I would say that rather than having the input be a list of 100 numbers, have the input be a single number and just have score be the sum of output lengths when applied to each of the 100 numbers. I think that this will avoid confusion over valid output formats, without altering the interesting part of the problem.

Comment: I would also say that this could be dangerously close to a [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124192/help-me-golf-my-numbers), since answers to that challenge seem likely to score well in this one with relatively minor modifications.

Comment: @KamilDrakari I'm trying to understand your suggestion. Currently the score *is* lowest sum of output lengths.

Comment: currently the challenge is for a program which takes a list of numbers and outputs 100 snippets. I think the challenge would be better if the program takes 1 number and outputs 1 snippet, and gets run 100 times to score it.

Comment: @KamilDrakari You're allowed to make a program that takes 1 snippet at a time, because you are score on the snippets, not the program. The program is a meta-program.

Comment: I think having both options should be more clearly stated then. One other suggestion: you mention "Lowest score in a particular language", which I think should be explicitly clarified whether answers compete based on the language of their snippets or their generating program.

Answer (score -2):

## Ulam spiral 2

Like Ulam, I had a boring moment and began drawing a spiral like him's. But his version is **utterly incorrect**, as the \ diagonal distorts the equation `n^2`.

The following picture illustrates an wrong Ulam spiral at left and a correct at right:

[image]

I challenge you to output a **numbered** Ulam spiral, the right version, where it is mandatory to **highlight the primes**. The input is `n`, meaning the point where the spiral ends. For the image example I gave `n` was `100`. It will always begin at `1`

I don't care what highlight style you use (different color, font weight, circle around number, etc), given it makes the primes easily distinguishable form the rest.

There will be no accepted answer; just did it for fun.

[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)  [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Comment: This isn't [arithmetic].

Comment: Also, can you provide an actual explanation of how you got the second one?

Comment: You can only have a maximum of 5 tags per question.

Comment: @Riker there is a pattern. Interpreting it is part of the challenge.

Comment: @sergiol -1, that's no fun at all.  The first person can figure it out, and the rest can and will copy the pattern.  PPCG doesn't work well with the "find the pattern _and_ decode it" style.

Comment: `wrong Ulam spiral at left`; I thought the spiral on the left was the Ulam spiral?

Comment: @JonathanFrech: Yes.

Answer (score -2):

Looking for some help to make this code golf/question better.

**Proposal:**

Now that twitter has increased it's character limit from 140 to 280, there's a joke of almost enough to write Hello World! in Java.   But what actual programs could you write in 280 characters, fizz buzz?  Sure you could write many in 140 or less, but maximum points if you get a good program in the full 280.

Comment: Hello! Your programming challenge needs an actual task... Think of an idea first, then come here again!

Comment: So "do something in exactly 280 bytes"? Yeah, you're going to need a much better spec than that. As well as a winning criterion.

Comment: There is some precedent for a [similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1696/71434), but that was more narrow, more clearly defined, and it was still closed for being "too broad" (though it did have some interesting answers). I don't think this would really offer any improvements over that existing challenge.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art is basically what you're describing except the limit is 280 rather than 140 characters

Answer (score -2):

## Shortest golang code to println the first byte of a function’s code

### Rules

- The code must be a function which takes another function as parameter and will print the first cpu instruction byte of parameter such as :

.

```
func dummy() {
}
print_first_native_instruction_byte(dummy)
```

would print :

```
0x90
```

which is a nop instruction on x86.

- You don’t need to perform disassembling : if the first instruction is longer than one byte, just print it’s first byte anyway without caring about instruction meaning or instruction length. Please note this is harder than just printing the value pointed by `&dummy` in the case of my example though.
- The function parameter must be a `go` function, not a `cgo` or assembly function.
- You can include as many golang packages as you want.
- The code need to be written in Go. **A well known language developped at Google and part of the four Google’s app engines supported languages** and answers should be able to run on the official [go playground](https://play.golang.org/).

### Winner

The one with the shortest code… Import statements included.

Comment: Please note this is a little harder than just getting the value of `&dummy` in my example code, and requires internal knowlwedge of the official go implementation. **but it doesn’t requires architecture specific code** beside handling big endian or little endian.

Answer (score -2):

## Preposition, not possession

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

### Enthralling background

Back in 1960s Soviet Russia, communism was the thing, and –– as we all know –– in a completely socialist society, there is ideally no personal property.

Our dear client is an author who is moving to the Soviet Union. However, as is Bolshevik custom, our client is afraid his works will be censored. That is why we are going to help this industrious author by revising his writings so that they will not be censored.

What will be censored? Any overt references to ownership.

How will we do this? Quite simply: we will replace all possession with preposition.

### Let's get specific

#### Example

```
Text in parenthesis is added; text in curly-brackets is removed.

[Input]   All the author's works will be censored!
[Output]  All (the works of )the author{'s works} will be censored!
```

#### Algorithmically

1. For each word with a `'s` attached to it:
2. Call the word with an `'s` attached to it `_word_`
3. Call the following word `_object_`
4. Remove all `'s`s and `_object_`
5. Insert `The _object_ of` two words before `_word_`
6. If there are not two words before `_word_`, place `_object_` right before `_word_`.

Here are some more examples:

```
Then the red horse stopped and took the orangutang's oranges. What a fuss ensued!
Then the red horse stopped and took the oranges of the orangutang. What a fuss ensued!

It is the people's right to not own anything!
It is the right of the people to not own anything!

The world's tallest building was once the Empire State Building.
The tallest of the world building was once the Empire State Building.

Bill likes Fred's shoes, and Jill likes Beth's dress.
Bill likes the shoes of Fred, and Jill likes the dress of Beth.

Ryan's fear was a stack overflow.
The fear of Ryan was a stack overflow.
```

Answer (score -2):

## Output the first digit of Graham's number

Code golf

Write a program that will output the first digit of Graham's number (and nothing else), terminate and produce no error.

I'll be lenient about loopholes. But if your submission is something like print("4"), the burden of proof will be on you.* Also, if you submit 9 answers like that, each printing one digit, then yes, one will definitely be correct, but I will need to know which one, and, you guessed it, the burden of proof is on you.*

* Catch: at the moment, no one has yet worked out what the first digit of Graham's number is.

But I want a "practical" solution. Yes, the algorithm is simple, but I'm sure your computer doesn't have unlimited storage. Nor do language implementations have arbitrarily large int. (OK, some do, but there is memory constraint.)

However, you will have a tape device attached to your computer. The library which is automatically loaded into the interpreter or compiler controls the tape device. Here things do become theoretical: the tape has a beginning, but no end, or you can imagine the device will manufacture more tape to extend it if more is needed. The tape has discrete positions. On each position a sector is stored. The device has access to one sector at the time but it can move the tape. All sectors have the same size.

The library provides you with the following functions (subroutines, whatever):
- detect if the tape is at the beginning
- move the tape left by n positions (stops at the beginning if sent beyond)
- move the tape right by n positions (n has to be one of atomic integer types of your chosen language)
- read the whole sector at current position
- read a part of the sector (zero indexed location within the sector and number of bytes to be read are arguments of an atomic integer type)
- overwrite the whole sector
- overwrite a part of the sector

The names of functions are your choice, as is the size of a sector. Reading loads the contents into a variable / into the memory area starting with a pointer given as an argument. Similar about writing.

Because the tape is effectively infinite, you have no function to tell you the actual position on the tape, as you'd have no way to store the result on a "real" computer.

So the real parts are: computer, possibly tape device.
Theoretical parts are:
- infinite storage tape or availability of material to manufacture as much tape as needed, which may well exceed the total amount of matter in our universe
- the computer, device, tape, ... not deteriorating, getting tangled up nor power falling or anything else going wrong for the time it takes the program to complete the task, which may well exceed total lifetime of our universe.

## Sandbox questions

Ideas how to improve the question... or should I abandon the idea?

Comment: As you say this is [tag:code-golf], I think you should better define your library functions (are they well-written and only require one-byte functions or is there considerable cost to using specific library features).

Comment: @JonathanFrech I thought I made clear about each of the 7 functions what they do. As for functions' names, some esoteric languages use funny identifiers so I thought I would leave naming to contestants. (I guess everyone will use single character names.) I'm open to suggestions if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: Some languages doesn't even have definition of "function" (BF, ///). Some other languages doesn't have definition of "extension/library" (Jelly). Practical is subjective. Sector size is not specified. Atomic integer type is not defined. The amount of memory the program takes depends on several things, not just the program.

Comment: @user202729 Maybe I should just name the functions and languages that can't handle named functions are out. Although brainfuck should be fine because its built-in commands will, using the library, manipulate the tape device (which enables it to be infinite, not possible otherwise); a sector would then probably only contain 8 or 16 bits. The solution in infinite brainfuck does indeed exist (because it's Turing complete) but how long is it?

Comment: Language specific things are heavily discouraged. I would expect some downvotes if you say that. / Some languages may already had that name as builtin (Mathematica `E`, `N`). / The issue of unclear-ness of other specifications still remains.

Comment: @user202729 What other specifications? Anyway, I'm trying to be as language-open as possible, but apart from very few I don't know of any other languages that actually have access to something infinite. So for other languages some kind of extension to get new actions is necessary. Is that too language specific? Maybe I should give up on this question, considering the popularity vote...

Answer (score -2):

## Golf an interpreter

The challenge is to find a path from A to B, but you must also provide an interpreter for your program.  The shortest interpreter wins.

**Input to path finder:**

A list of edges in a graph e.g.

```
AC
CD
DB
```

**Output from path finder:**

A list of vertices e.g. `A C D B`

Feel free to somewhat adjust the input/output format.

**Scoring:**

Your score is the number of bytes of your interpreter/compiler.  The lowest score wins.

**Note:**

It's possible to work around the question and interpret a language that is too similar to an existing one by doing something like:

```
eval(input_file.replace("this never happens", ""))
```

I don't have a good rule to prevent this other than to ask that you don't.

Comment: Not interesting, so downvote. Yes, you can't restrict that.

Answer (score -2):

### Brainf*** Polygot

[polygot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygot)[brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Write a brainf*** interpreter in as many languages as possible.

You will take the brainf*** code on standard input, and then execute it.

Your score is `bytes / (n * sqrt n)` (where n is the number of languages in which your program works), which you will seek to minimize.

Comment: I don't think the generic "preform <simple task> in as many languages as possible" [polyglot] task is gonna cut it anymore. Maybe add some new BF-related task.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit This isn't "preform some simple task". This is "be Turing complete". No other polygot challenge can be used a universal turing machine.

In particular, it requires you to use the turing complete facilities of all the languages involved.

Comment: If your goal is "prove turing completeness", then maybe "write a polyglot interpreter for a Turing-complete language". Allow different languages to interpret different TC languages.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I guess that would make it more interesting. I kind of like the idea of them all doing the same thing though, so you can just "feed in" an algorithm and get an instant polygot.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit What about a caveat that the you must feed in the currently executing language as a parameter (for example, when run with python, it executes the code with "python" as its first input).

Comment: In my opinion, polyglot challenges are better when you're solving different problems in each language. That has the advantage of being more interesting to solve, as well as not needing to ban multiple similar versions of the same language (since making polyglots would be trivial in those).

Comment: Alternatively, a more difficult version: a polyglot in some set of languages languages that acts a compiler from BF to a new polyglot in each of those languages. In that case you probably want to score by no. of languages

Comment: @EsolangingFruit OW, that sounds even cooler!

Answer (score -2):

## Gatherer Golf: The 61 Dwarves

[Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) is the official tool for searching for Magic: The Gathering cards. Its advanced mode allows searching by most of the criteria you could hope for, as well as simple boolean combinations within a single kind of criterion (for example, you can do "name contains X or Y and not Z").

I've been using it a lot recently, and have been trying to get better at more quickly finding the exact set of cards I need. For example, if I want creatures that can generate mana, searching for ["dd {"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&type=+[%22Creature%22]&text=+[%22add%20%7B%22]) seems to be the minimal exact string match on their rules text.

For this inaugural Gatherer Golf, your challenge is to create a query that lists, exactly, the 61 Dwarf cards (not counting creatures that are all creature types), without using the key "subtype". The result generated the normal way can be found [here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+[%22Dwarf%22]).

**Rules**

- Your score is the length of the full URL in Gatherer. For example, searching for "name contains Dw or Resp and type contains Creature" generates the URL `gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&name=|[Dw]|[Resp]&type=+[%22Creature%22]` for a score of 104.

  - Lowest score wins.
  - Your URL can be manually generated; it doesn't have to be possible to create it via the advanced search form.
  - Cards added to Gatherer after this challenge was posted (in this case, after Rivals of Ixalan) do not invalidate existing answers. Your answer may include or exclude any card published after that date, regardless of whether it's a dwarf, and answers that no longer give correct results (for example, because the Oracle text of a card changed) do not need to be deleted.
  - Other than as described above, all cards in Gatherer are relevant to this challenge, regardless of whether they're legal for tournament play.
  - Don't DOS Gatherer or otherwise break its terms of service.
  - The cards may be listed in any order. This may be relevant if your search contains more than just dwarves, but concentrates all the dwarves into one page of the search results.

Comment: I'm not sure that this requires code to solve.  Also, I'd ban the word "subtype" in the query, as that's more solid than "without querying on subtype"

Comment: Thanks, edited. I was thinking of the query itself as code--it's declarative and certainly doesn't meet our definition of a programming language, but I'd've expected an HTML or SQL golfing challenge to be on-topic here and this seems the same in principle.

Comment: I wouldn't expect HTML golfing to be on-topic; and SQL meets the definition of a programming language. IMO the way to make this on-topic is to somehow supply a database (maybe abusing imgur with steganography?) and then ask for a program which takes input as a list of card names to match and outputs a minimal query.

Answer (score -2):

## xkcd-esque Reverse Code Golf

### Introduction

A new [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1960/) came out recently, seemed to be a fun challenge and a change from the usual code golfing.

[image]

So I set out on making this challenge!

### Challenge

Make a short snippet of code in any language which, when read out, sounds like  1 sentence of normal English literature (for example, Moby Dick in the comic).

### Rules

- The snippet doesn't have to run, so you are free to add statements which would not execute (for example: undeclared variables, functions, etc.). However, it must be syntactically correct.
- A word in this challenge is any sequence of letters considered as valid English as in a dictionary. Articles (a, an, the) are counted as words.
- To prevent too long answers, the maximum number of words will be fixed at 200 individual words. This includes operator expansion.
- The maximum length of any function or variable name will be 10 words.
- The expansion used for an operator must be specified in the answer.
- Imported and built-in functions are not considered as operators.
- Since this is *reverse* code golf, the answer with the **most** points wins.

Scoring criteria:

- **Characters used to structure code (0)**: All kinds of brackets, statement terminators, whitespace, etc.
- **Comments and String literals (0)**: To avoid making large comments/literals with actual literature
- **Names of functions or variables (1 per character)**:
- **Keywords (2 per letter)**: Using keywords in the story as valid syntax.
- **Operators (2 per letter of expansion)**: For example, `>` is worth 2x13 (isGreaterThan).

## Examples

Valid:

```
try { throw IngTheBallAnd; } catch (Ing it) {}
// Worth 3x2 + 5x2 + 13 + 5x2 + 3 + 5 = 37 points

let myLife = "a quote";
// Worth 3x2 + 6 + 2x2 = 16 points ("=" used as "be")
```

Invalid:

```
// One does not simply write everything in a comment
// Worth 0
```

Hope this meets PPCG puzzle criteria :D

Comment: Define "short" Otherwise answers could just go on and on to approach infinite score.

Comment: How long may function/variable names be?

Comment: How do we determine the exact expansion of operators? E.g. is `*` "times" or "multipliedBy"?

Comment: So the APL function [`××`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0w9P///fWCFNwZDLBEgacBkBSV0jLgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") would count as 28: (signOfTheTimes)? Indeed APL functions often read nicely as plain English. E.g. [`(?∘≢⊃⊢)¨(⊂⍳3)/⍨¨1+⊢`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91722/43319) reads as "a random number up to (`?`) the length (`≢`) selects from (`⊃`) the value of (`⊢`) each of (`¨`) the entire (`⊂`) indices until (`⍳`) three (`3`) replicated (`/`) by (`⍨`) each of (`¨`) one (`1`) added to (`+`) the value of the argument (`⊢`).

Comment: @Adám I'll edit my answer to answer these. As for APL, I guess my puzzle is no match for it :P

Comment: @Adám I'd actually aim for english *literature* rather than procedure sentences

Comment: What is a "determiner"? Some programming languages do not use white space. What is a word?

Comment: "Context" determination of expansion is not an exact science. As long as your challenge has that feature, I predict it will be closed as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Are built-in functions "keywords"? What about imported functions?

Comment: @Adám Edited to answer. Determiners were meant to be Articles (a, an, the). Lack of whitespace is not a concern as long as it is readable. I mentioned the need for specifying the intended meaning of operators before, but it was a partial change.

Comment: *built-in functions are not considered as operators*? Uh, what exactly is an operator then? Some languages use single letters as operators. I'm afraid this question makes far too many assumptions about the features of programming languages. A common mistake, but often hard to fix. Compare to the problems with [atomic code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/atomic-code-golf/info).

Comment: There have been a few questions about reading code as sentences, e.g. [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5760), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21095), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22864). Because answers can't be objectively scored, those are [tag:popularity-contests]. However those types of challenge have mostly fallen out of scope on the site and are very hard to get right, see the [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info) for more infos.

Comment: Hmm.... alrighty. I shall disband this puzzle. I hope someone can make a better puzzle with the comic, it ought to get its own challenge ;)

Comment: No one have said that? Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Note that this is called [tag:code-bowling] on PPCG. Typically code bowling questions have strict scoring rules to avoid arbitrary score inflation which usually prevents large variable/function names.

Comment: @JoKing Ah I see, thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

## Bees?

Inspired by [SCP-3045](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-3045)

Write a program that takes the input, extracts all of the words, and looks for the word `bee`; then:

- If `bee` is not detected, pick sections of the text at random and delete them.
- If `bee` is detected, add instances of the word `bee` to the input such that it has significantly more bytes than the original input.

The program should then output these modifications.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: How much is *significantly more*? Why is it popularity-contest?

Comment: *Do X creatively* pop cons have fallen out of scope. This will get closed instantly if posted on main.

Answer (score -2):

**Move a window around the screen**

Your code should open  a new window that is at least 100 by 100 pixels in size.  Once the window is open you should be able to move the window around the screen using the keyboard.  The window should move smoothly but it doesn't matter how fast it moves.

[gui](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Is there anything else that could make this challenge a bit more interesting? Maybe a scoring method?

Comment: @RamenChef I suppose the scoring method was meant to be by the code-golf rules. I could make the challenge more interesting maybe by insisting that you can type into the window?

Comment: What counts as a "*window*"? I think this might be quite hard to define objectively in a way which is OS-agnostic.

Answer (score -2):

## Let's play the too high too - low game!

**TL:DR : write a code that plays the too high - too low game**

---

Given this pseudo code function for the too high - too low game, write it in your language of choice. This is just to make the challenge work better across all languages. This code won't count in the final score. You may also change the function's name and any of its variable's name too.

```
function isRight(number, guess):  # where the number is the correct answer and the guess is your code's guess

    if guess < number:            # if the guess is too low
        return 0                  # return 0

    else if guess > number:       # if the guess is too high
        return 2                  # return 2

    else if guess == number:      # if the guess is right
        return 1                  # return 1

    else:                         # if there is an error
        return -1                 # return -1
```

---

## The challenge

Write a code, function, script, etc. that guesses the right number. The range of the "random" number will be between 0 inclusively and 100 exclusively. For the sake of this challenge, the "random" numbers will be the test cases. Note that hard-coding the test cases is banned.

---

## Scoring

This is how the score will be counted:

```
bytes = number of bytes in your code
tries = the sum of all the tries used to guess all the test cases

score = bytes + tries
```

---

## Rules

- Hard-coding the test cases if forbidden.

---

## Test cases

```
[0,2,4,13,19,21,26,33,38,42,48,50,51,56,66,69,74,75,80,89,98,99]
```

Comment: For one, i'd say the randomness is unfair. If you manipulate the seed python is given, you can just have it output a known sequence. Alongside that, can't you just hardcode the testcase?

EDIT: Hardcoding the test case is the only way to get a good score.

Comment: @moonheart08 would banning hardcoding the test cases help?

Comment: "_the sum of all the tries used to guess all the test cases_" Won't this be the same for all answers (with the only difference being floor vs ceil when taking halve the previous guess (as in 75 & higher could result in a next guess of either 87 or 88).First guess will always be `50`. Is it lower, guess 25; is it higher, guess 75. etc. etc. Btw, there are already a few Guess the number challenges: [Here is one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/guess-the-number); and [here is another one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11232/guess-my-number-code-golf).

Answer (score -2):

## Output a Random Bit

[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Your task is simple: print either `1` or `0`.

Chosen uniformly *randomly* every time.

No, not your silly *pseudo*random nonsense. No system calls. No reading `/dev/urandom`. The randomness has to be unpredictable (i.e. reliant on chaotic, impossible-to-reasonably-model natural phenomena, and not on some configuration of bits in your computer).

### Specifications

- It is OK to query a site such as [random.org](https://random.org) for your bit.
- Your program only needs to be runnable once per day (i.e. you can assume there is a 24 hour gap between executions). This is to work around the fact that sites like random.org often have rate-limits.

Comment: If it only has to be run once a day, wouldn't `millis() % 2` be truly random?

Comment: @geokavel No, because you can't assume that the calling actions will be random (e.g. I could always invoke the program at 25-hour intervals, meaning that `millis() % 2` would always be a consistent value.

Comment: Is a time cost of maybe read a file in nanoseconds allowed?

Comment: In its current form, it appears to be impossible to define the validity criteria objectively. Temporary -1.

Comment: @user202729 If it were up to you, how would you define them?

Comment: /dev/random seems to be really random. Is it allowed?

Comment: @someone Wikipedia says it's a PRNG, and I've heard that system randomness tends to draw entropy from sources like startup times and user actions, so that wouldn't count.

Comment: Would a HRNG such as RdRand work?

Comment: ... I admit that my downvote/comment is not constructive, but I found absolutely no way to objectively define the challenge.

Comment: Maybe define "real random" as "not only based on xxx"(currently last state, calling current)

Comment: @l4m2 That was what I was trying to imply by saying it shouldn't be pseudorandom.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit but you need to define what's pseudo

Answer (score -2):

## ♫ *I see a window and I want it painted black* ♫

Yes, I know this is a popular mishearing of the lyrics. But instead of a red door, I really do want an (application) window painted black.

Your standalone program should launch an application window at least 400x400 and fill it entirely with black. It doesn't need to be borderless, and it doesn't need to exit gracefully.

Running in a browser is insufficient because there are still elements of the window such as the address-bar and tab-bar that aren't painted black. You must paint the whole window black except for borders added by your window manager.

This is code golf. Standard loopholes apply. Additional challenge is to listen to The Rolling Stones while making your submission.

Here is an un-golfed Java solution:

```
#compile: javac BlackWindow.java
#run: java BlackWindow
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class BlackWindow{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Frame frame = new Frame("no colors anymore");
    frame.setsize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setBackground(Color.Black);
    frame.setvisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if my platform doesn't support windows that large?

Comment: What is the 400x400 measured in? Pixels? Does it qualify if I somehow emulate a screen with larger resolution?

Comment: Does making the whole screen black count?

Comment: Stephen then make the whole screen black? What kind of system doesn't support that?

Comment: user202729 i was thinking pixels

Comment: What if I am listening to The Feelies cover of the song? Do I get the bonus point? +1 from me for an unusual challenge.

Answer (score -2):

(Now I don't know what the name should be)

## Intention

I want to create a challenge based on dependent typing, feature that exists in Idris, Coq, Agda and the similiar.

## Text

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

You should create a function in dependently typed language (Idris, Coq, Agda, etc) so that:

1. The function will receive a string that denotes format.
2. The format string will have s or n, s means it will receive a string, n means it will receive a number. You can assume that there is no other thing in the string
3. Arguments is received in order. If there is type mismatch, the error must be reported on compile-time.
4. After all arguments is received, the function will return a string, that is list of all passed argument

For example

```
formatf "sn" "goods" 25
> "goods 25"
formatf "sn" "goods" "bad"
> Type error in compile time
formatf "ak" "Akangka" 25
> You can do anything.
formatf "nnn" 24 25
> Either type error or return a function expecting a number and return string (currying is almost universal in these languages)
formatf "ss" "Akangka" "Martin Ender" "Adám"
> Type error on compile time
```

This challenge is similiar to [printf-style string formatting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17297/46245), the difference that the function in this challenge has to be type safe.

Note that you cannot use build-in function or macro to do this

## Discussion

1. What should be the name of this challenge?

Comment: Any reason why full programs are not allowed?

Comment: What happens if the language is not compiled?

Comment: (if you didn't realize, it's not just some languages can't solve it, but in some languages your requirements don't make any sense. There are languages without functions, language with only monadic functions, languages without integers, language without macros, language where macros have different meaning than C `#define`, language without string (C), etc.)

Comment: If the string is possibly not known at compile time, how can it produce a type error at compile time?

Comment: Personally I think it's a bit too similar to the challenge you linked.. The only difference is validating the input-type with the format.. In which case it would be better to have a challenge dedicated to that, as in: Given this format and a variable amount of other objects, check if the format and types of these objects match. In which case `"%s: %i%%", "Percentage", 25` would be truthy, and `"%s: %i%%", 123.45, 25` would be falsey. In addition, most languages are type independent, which can change during run-time based on their use.. `10.0` could be all three types in some languages..

Comment: Suggested re-working of the problem: Given a pattern using only `%s` and `%n` (for number), slot in the given list of strings and numbers in the given order, but return a distinct value or throw an error if the given list doesn't fit right.

Comment: @Angs dependent typing. In fact, this challenge is about dependent typing.

Comment: @user202729 well, by compile-time, I mean about typechecking time. I specifically disallow dynamic typing, as one of the point of the challenge is to make the program fail to typecheck if `%s` format is supplied by integer, etc.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Indeed, not all language can do this challenge. After all the intention is on the dependent typing, which most programming language (but not Idris, Coq, etc) lack.

Comment: @Adám nice suggestion. But the type-safe feature (i.e. all error is on type-checking time) is integral part of the challenge

Comment: @Akangka I don't understand why my suggestion doesn't satisfy that. You get a list of strings and numbers and need to check against each tag in the format that you've been given the right tag.

Comment: I think you should limit to some languages (perhaps extend  the language list if needed), as the challenge does not make sense in other languages anyway.

Comment: @Adám I actually implement your suggestion, except the throw an error part. I make the challenge require the result is type error

Comment: @Akangka I don't understand why you insist on language specific features like "type errors" and "compile time". Your examples do not show how to format `ss`, `ns`, and `nn`. You mention float dots, but floats are not part of the examples any more.

Comment: @Adám thanks about float dots. About language specific features, I just want to create a challenge about dependent typing.

Answer (score -2):

## Shorter coding in non-golfing language

Copper write a requirement, a sample program in a golfing language, and a required non-golfing language. Rob hack it with the required language, with fewer bytes of code.

I guess it'd be [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) cuz it's sometimes hard to define which is "golfing language". Also is it a duplicate?

Comment: If it's a [tag:cops-and-robbers], then it can't be a [tag:popularity-contest]. I personally don't think this challenge would work out; first of all, it's virtually impossible to outgolf a golfing language using a non-golfing languages because most golfing languages can complete most reasonable tasks in fewer bytes than it takes a non-golfing language to even print Hello World. Also like you said, golfing/non-golfing is extremely difficult to define. I also don't think this challenge would be particularly interesting because you'd likely end up with a bunch of miscellaneous cops posts with all

Comment: sorts of random requirements, which is basically just going to be a bunch of questions that either exist on PPCG already or could be posted to PPCG main as its own challenge, without any robber posts because it would be basically impossible.

Comment: IMO this is well past the threshold of "Too Broad", so I would vote to close for that reason.

Answer (score -2):

### The challenge

- Write a Discord bot with a single command, `!oldest`, that gives the oldest user in the server that the command that was run in.
- Gracefully failing in DM channels is not required.
- Assume the bot's token is this invalid token: `MjM4NDk0NzU2NTIxMzc3Nzky.CunGFQ.wUILz7z6HoJzVeq6pyHPmVgQgV4`.
  If the token is compressed in the program, provide instructions on how to change it so I can test it.

### Sample discord.py implementation

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(M):
 if(M.content=="!oldest"):
  N=sorted([x.id for x in M.server.members])[1]
  await client.send_message(M.channel, str(M.server.get_member(N)))
client.run("MjM4NDk0NzU2NTIxMzc3Nzky.CunGFQ.wUILz7z6HoJzVeq6pyHPmVgQgV4")
```

1. Get a list of every user in the server
2. Sort their snowflake IDs
3. Print the username and discriminator of the member with the smallest ID.

No API for your language? Have fun.

Standard loopholes forbidden, etc, etc.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

## Sandbox

I originally posted this question on the main site, but I deleted it, as it turns out I'm bad at writing these. Please forgive me.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this already, but with comments saying that it needed a lot more information to be self-contained. It still needs a lot more information to be self-contained.

Comment: Yep. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Are you talking about *discord* servers? Other than form the example this is not clear at all. What is a `DM` channel? What is a *token* in this context?

Comment: A: Clarify that you're talking about Discord  
B: When you make a challenge that requires a library does that mean I can use a library that conveniently has the command you're asking of?

Answer (score -2):

## Quecho, a quine-like implementation of echo.

## Challenge:

Your challenge is to write a quine-like program that takes a string from stdin and gives two outputs: Output A is the input string. Output B is your source code.

## Output Formats:

You can send your outputs to stdout, stderr, and/or files. If A and B go to the same output, they must be separated by a newline. Having a newline at the beginning of your source doesn't count. You'd need to print that newline from your source and then another newline to separate A and B.

## Examples:

source: `print($stdin+"\n"+codeThatGeneratesSource)`

input: `Hello, World!`

#### Both outputs on stdout:

```
Hello, World!
print($stdin+"\n"+codeThatGeneratesSource)
```

#### Separate Outputs:

stdout: `Hello, World!`

stderr: `print($stdin+"\n"+codeThatGeneratesSource)`

#### [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10033) are forbidden.

#### Submissions should be [proper quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878) except that they produce the additional specified output.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66276/quat-quine-cat

Comment: Good find. Not a dupe because that calls for either printing the source *or* printing the input, not both. Also it requires testing length of input, where this does not.

Comment: How is this any different from that, though? The concept of printing the source and printing the output is the same, and I can't see how only a small tweak wouldn't be able to port an answer between the challenges.

Answer (score -2):

- This is in sandbox to check whether or not to repost the BrainF**k interpreter challenge. The links have been given in credits.
- Should comment handling be required.
- Also any other improvements are welcome

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)

## BrainF**k:

BrainF**k is an esoteric programming language designed in the 90s. The reason for its fame is that understanding a program longer than 10 characters in the language is quite hard.

**Example program :**

```
>++++++++[<++++++++>-]<++++++++++++++++.[-]
```

*Guess what this does.*

---

## Commands:

Brainf**k operates on an array of memory cells, also referred to as the **tape**, each initially set to `zero`. There is a *pointer*, initially pointing to the *first memory cell*.

There are a total of eight commands in BF and these are as follows:

```
Command       |                              Purpose
  >           |      increment the data pointer (to point to the next cell to the right).
  <           |      decrement the data pointer (to point to the next cell to the left).
  +           |      increment (increase by one) the byte at the data pointer. 
  -           |      decrement (decrease by one) the byte at the data pointer.
  .           |      output the byte at the data pointer
  ,           |      one byte of input, storing its value in the byte at the data pointer.
  [           |      if the byte at the data pointer is zero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it forward to the command after the matching ] command.
  ]           |      if the byte at the data pointer is nonzero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it back to the command after the matching [ command.
```

---

## Note :

`+` and `-` operators increment and decrement the bytes at the at the data pointer, note that if the value reaches `255` then upon a `+` it would become `0`.

```
255 + 1 = 0
```

Similarly if the value reaches `0` then upon the next `-` it would become `255`.

```
0 - 1 = 255
```

---

## Input:

You will be given two strings as input:

- The actual BrainF**k code that you are supposed to interpret.
- the program input (`that will eventually be emptied`) to be interpreted as an array of bytes using each character's ASCII code and will be consumed by the `,` instruction

## Example:

```
Program : +[,>,]<.
stdin   : 11111
```

---

## Output:

- the output of the interpreted code, if any was produced by the `.` instruction.

## Example:

For the above mentioned program, the output should be:

```
output: 1
```

---

## Notes:

- Both `program` and `stdin` will be given as strings.
- The output should be a string showing the result after operations.
- Given input will always be valid, with a valid BrainF**k program.
- In order to avoid confusion, note that you do not need to output the word `output` as well

e.g :

```
 output : 1
```

in this your output should only be 1. (asked by @Picard)

## Credits:

The question was (more or less) already asked [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainf).
This has been reposted since that was 7 years old and was outdated as well.

Meta posts on that:

- [Asked by me regarding my repost now.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16475/interpret-bf-question-on-repost).
- [Another one, about reposts in general.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/duplicate-questions)
- [Martin Ender's post about closing old questions in favor of new.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/closing-old-question-as-duplicate-of-a-new-one?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

## Examples:

```
Program: +[>>>>+++++[-<++>]<[-<++++++++++>]<[-<<->>]<<-[>-<[-]]>+<,]>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]++++++++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[->>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[.[-]<]<
stdin: Hello, World. This is a program for checking eeeeeeee. Well I have plenty of e
output: 14

Program: ++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
stdin: 
output: Hello, World
```

---

## Winning-criteria:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork : So i should put `nothing` ?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork : Thanks, done.

Comment: I think some of your notes are too ambiguous to be useful. In particular, "You can have numbers as output where numbers are expected" and "The input will be what it should be" seem to just be... "You are allowed to output numbers if you're allowed to output numbers" and "You can assume that the input is the input"

Comment: Also, it would be good to clarify whether the BF commands are the *only* characters that will be in the program string, or if we are required to handle other characters as comments.

Comment: @KamilDrakari : Changed. Hopefully better

Comment: @KamilDrakari : I think I will put that as something I would like to know (reasons why this is sandboxed)\

Comment: I don't believe comment handling would be interesting, so I would rather leave it as "you may assume the program input contains no characters other than ><+-.,[]"

Comment: @KamilDrakari : Okay

Comment: What happens if you move left of the starting position on the tape? Is it undefined behaviour or does it have to work?

Comment: @wastl : undefined behaviour is ok.

Comment: 3 things: 1, you need to explain how the memory tape works. You hvaen't really explained that. 2, you should clarify that the output doesn't need to say literally `output: 1`, you should really allow just `1`. 3, don't really bother with comments, it's basically just ignoring other characters.

Comment: 1. Hopefully done, 2. done, 3. Ok, 2 votes for not having comments.

Comment: What if our language has only one input stream? Can we also accept input as the program and input separated by a `!` (or some other character)?

Comment: @JoKing : yes, you can

Answer (score -2):

## Longest reference

Write two code A and B, where len(A)<=1024, running A returns B and running B returns A. Longest B win.

Proper quine rule and no rubbish rule(for code-bowling) apply.

> Un-used Code
>
> All code must be used. Meaning the program must fail to always properly complete the task if any individual character (or varying set(s) of characters) is/are removed. Naturally, a subset of the program should not be able complete the task on its own without the rest of the program.

[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver)

## Sandbox notes

- The "1024" may change

Comment: Actually we have no standard rule for code-bowling to prevent unused code.

Comment: (although for this particular challenge, it's not possible to make program arbitrarily long)

Comment: It's pretty easy to abuse this one. Program `A` prints program `C` `n` times, where program `C` prints program `A` and then comments out any further copies of `C`. Make `n` as large as you can and it's easy. Good [tag:code-bowling] challenges usually have more restrictions

Comment: @JoKing Your solution seems to break the "no rubbish rule"

Comment: As user202729 says, there is no standard "rubbish rule". And if there was, there would be many ways of getting around it.

Comment: Suggestion: Why not have the challenge be to minimise the length of `A` while maximising the length of `B`? I'm not sure what the scoring system would be though...

Comment: @JoKing I really like that idea but I don't think it would solve the problem. The issue is that `B` can still contain "rubbish", so it becomes a kind of [tag:busy-beaver] problem for `A` to print the largest amount of nonfunctional code in `B`.

Comment: The "unused code" test is unlikely to be practical for programs longer than about 100 characters.

Answer (score -2):

## Sort on an infinite-dimension cube

Given a [unit cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cube) in the \$n\$-dimensional space. Assume that the vertices of the cube has coordinate \$(x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\$ where \$x_i \in \{0,1\} \forall i\in \mathbb N, 0\le i<n\$.

It's possible to number all vertices with non-negative integers less than \$2^n\$. In this challenge, the vertex with coordinate \$(x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\$ will be assigned with number \$2^0\times x_0+2^1\times x_1+\dots+2^n\times x_n\$.

Each vertex can hold an integer.

In this challenge, you can assume \$n\$ contains a very large (practically infinite) value.

---

Given \$4096\$ items placing in vertex 0 - vertex 4095, you're to sort them. Other vertices contain undefined values, and may be modified by the program.

However, the program cannot directly access the values held by the vertices. You can only control a memory pointer `M`, which always lie at a vertex of the cube (call this vertex `V`). Initially `M` is at the coordinate \$(0,0,0,\dots)\$. This memory pointer can store exactly 1 integer value.

The following operations on the memory pointer `M` are alllowed:

- Store the value held by `V` into memory of `M`.
- Write the value stored by `M` into `V`.
- Compare value stored by `M` and value held by `V`. This operation should report to the program 3 different values based on whether the comparison is \$<\$, \$=\$ or \$>\$.
- Move along an edge (in the direction specified by the program) of the cube. This corresponds to changing exactly 1 coordinate of `M` from `0` to `1`, or vice versa.

Your score is the distance traveled by the memory pointer.

---

A psuedo-code sample interaction library may be:

```
obj[Infinity] = {[4096 values]}
ptr = 0, cry = undefined
function move(i): ptr = ptr xor (1 shl i)
function carry(): cry = obj[ptr]
function place(): obj[ptr] = cry
function compare(): return sgn(obj[ptr] - cry)
```

You can write functions, use IO, or anyway to interact. Lowest `move` callings win.

Comment: Actually I think there are just 12 dimensions.

Comment: @user202729 More dimensions exist and you can use them, but they are initally empty

Comment: What does it mean to sort an infinite-dimension cube? Currently this very unclear.

Comment: @Laikoni I'd say code shows enough to understand, so it's not ready to post but not unclear

Comment: No, sorry, it's not so clear to the rest of us. I have no idea what the input is, what the output is, even what `obj` we're working with and how it relates to an "infinite dimension cube". Many of your questions here (including this one) seem to contain something interesting in them, but they'd be much better received if you post them on the chat room first and explained what you had in mind, and got some help with the question text, at least to the level that they can be meaningfully discussed on. That way your challenges will reach more people too.

Comment: @sundar I think the sandbox is exactly the place for improving challenges. I'm not sure if using the chat room is necessary.

Comment: @Laikoni Better now?

Answer (score -2):

## Golf a regex that matches syntactically valid programs in the language of your choice.

1:  Pick a programming language, *P*, that meets these requirements:

- *P* is known to be Turing-Complete.
- *P* has a freely available and working compiler or interpreter.

2:  Create a regular expression, *R*, such that:

- *R* matches any string that is a syntactically valid program of *P*.
- *R* rejects any string that is a syntactically invalid program of *P*

3: Golf *R*. Shortest regex wins.

Comment: For a lot of Esolangs it would just be `.*`, I think you'd need to restrict the languages to something that doesn't allow any string `ALPHABET*` or `ALPHABET+`. Also you'd need to specify a regex flavour.

Comment: Warning: Most low-level languages are not known to be TC. For example C (which is only recently proved TC, AFAIK. [Ref](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60965/is-c-actually-turing-complete))

Comment: Hm. `int main(){int x=__builtin_popcount(1);}` is not syntactically valid C (undefined identifier), but it compiles in GCC. Also, most compilers don't allow too long identifiers. What do you think?

Comment: @user202729: I doubt that you'll find a regex for C (or pretty much any non-esoteric, high-level language) anyways since most of the time you need to check if `()` are balanced.

Comment: @OMᗺ Just saying...... // For the first comment, typically the answerer just specify the regex flavor in the answer.

Comment: Because only _those_ high-level languages have a proper definition of what is a syntax error. The low-level languages are often just "what the interpreter complains about", and there are still different forms of error -- assertion error, runtime, return 1, ....

Answer (score -2):

## Largest and Smallest Numbers Printable

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [palindrone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrone) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

*Related: [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/48922)*

Your goal is to write code that produces a large number. However, when your code is reversed, you must output a *small* number.

#### Rules

- No constants over 10 (like the other challenge)
- *No numeric literals*
- No infinite numbers
- Each program can only output one number
- You must have at least two bytes in your program.
- Your small number must be less than your large number.

#### Scoring:

Your score is: \$\frac{code~length}{N_{large} - N_{small}}\$. Smallest score wins.

Comment: Ban numeric literals. having the code of n 9's and n 0's in a golving language with auto output results in having a score of \$\frac{2n}{(10^n-1)^2}\$ which will go to 0 for arbitrary large n

Comment: Even with "no constant over 10" the strategy above will still works in languages such as `cat`.

Comment: @kroppeb that's interesting, thanks.

Comment: Like the other challenge I'd suggest a maximum code length and putting a higher penalty on code length. Also, are we allowed to print negative numbers?

Answer (score -2):

### The Tiniest Generic Evolutionary AI

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ai](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

---

**Introduction**

The smallest program you can make (measured in bytes) that builds evolving AIs that parses unknown text string A into unknown text string  B that still evolves.

All languages are options. Internet connectivity is allowed (but not providing any specific links). The AI must have a choice of commands (allowing variables) from a Turing Complete instruction set.

---

**Scoring**

Scoring is two fold:
N = Number of bytes of program (ignoring size of AIs generated)

T = The average generations (generations of 200 AIs or less) before your program can evolve an AI that can do the 5 test cases.

Score = 1000/(N*T)

---

**Challenge**

Rules:
Using the fewest bytes possible, create a generic evolutionary AI that will evolve to parse one supplied but previously unknown string into another supplied but previously unknown string.

What qualifies as an evolutionary AI in this context:

```
Your Code
Takes an input string
Takes a seed AI Instruction Set(s)
Runs AI Instruction Sets
Rates Each AI Instruction Set against others and against test strings
Evolves AI to create a new set of AI Instruction Set(s) through random mutation and breeding of existing AIs.
=================
AI Code
Is not written by you (except for possibly a seed AI), to be created by your program instead.
Uses a set of *available* instructions that are or are inspired by a known Turing complete instruction set (such as RISC)
Should consist of references to the available instructions and values for them.
```

1. The code you write does not parse the strings directly. Instead, it writes output that is a collection of instructions, and reads in a collection of instructions and applies these instructions. (Ugly as it may be, eval is allowed).
2. It reads in multiple optional instruction sets.
3. It rates those instruction sets based on which gets closest to parsing the input string into the target string.
4. The best performing instructions sets are encouraged in some way.
5. The worst performing instruction sets are discouraged and/or eliminated in some way.
6. Using existing AI-oriented libraries is discouraged.
7. Allowing evolutionary AIs to use develop using a turing-complete set of instructions is encouraged. (Example solution uses a modified RISC instruction set.)
8. Instruction sets must be able to mutate (randomly change) between generations. They are allowed to breed (selectively change) between generations as well.
9. Multiple iterations of comparing and evolving instructions sets is possible.
10. How quickly your AIs evolve or how well they do the job doesn't matter so much as they can get better at the task over iterations.
11. A seed starting instruction set is allowed. If your solution requires an inputed file for an initial instruction set, a functional example is required and counts towards the byte count.
12. It handles if an instruction set it runs fails to complete, or times out if an AI instruction set goes on too long (default to 30 seconds).
13. Program must accept in one arbitrary string from a source. (Your choice of a generic commonly used source, such as a web form, command line, or file). It outputs each AI instruction set's result in a similar format it took them in. It may also optionally accept a starter AI set of instructions.
14. The AI code never gets to interact with the test string it's being graded against.
15. Your program cannot do any string conversions on the input string on its own, only may act as it's instructed to by the AI.
16. A seed AI is not allowed to have anything more than a start, end, or return call of some kind (it must evolve any processing steps on its own).

---

**Test Cases:**

Can the program evolve an AI that approaches being capable of string conversion of an unknown conversion? (It is recommended not to build the AI to these specific test cases, these are for the point of testing genericness. Do not specifically target these cases until reporting results, and others testing your program may test them against other string conversions and rate accordingly.)

Five examples follow -

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

will be converted into

```
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

or possibly

```
1010101100110101011001
```

will be converted into

```
0101010011001010100110
```

or possibly

```
"Mary had a little lamb."
```

will be converted into

```
"Gary had a little ham."
```

or possibly

```
"Banana"
```

will be converted to

```
"Banananananananananananananananana."
```

Or maybe

The entire text of the Bible

will be converted to

The entire text of the Bible, but every instance of "sheep" is replaced with "codfish".

---

**Short Diagram of interaction.**

```
   STEP 1                         STEP 2                     STEP 3  ...

 Input String           ->
 Expected Output String ->   Your Code Starts  ->    Assorted AI Instruction sets. ->      ->        ->       ->      Your Code Processes AI Instruction Sets -> Your code compares, mutates, and breeds AIs to create new generation -> Return to Step 3
 Seed AI                ->                     (Example: AI1 -> Start(Input); Output(Input)
                                                         AI2 -> Start(Input); CP(Mem1, Mem2); Output (Mem2);)
```

---

**Example**

An on-a-whim project done that roughly followed these rules and inspired this challenge that ran <1000 lines of code (although short, it did not aim for minimal characters.)

[myLittleAI](https://github.com/joshupetersen/myLittleAi)

Comment: There are a lot of restrictions and rules, however there is no clear description of the task itself: What does "*parse one string into another string*" mean? About the rules: Overriding loop-holes such as allowing internet-connectivity is likely to create problems or allow boring answers. "*Answer must evolve using options that are or are inspired by a Turing complete instruction set.*" seems like it's a non-observable requirement (and you override the rule in the second rule anyways). Why do you want to disallow libraries?

Comment: Some of the other rules don't make sense to me, but it's likely to be caused by me not being able to understand the challenge itself.

Comment: @BMO Reason to disallow libraries is that there are existing libraries that are AI libraries. Allowing them means you just call some monolithic AI library and you're done. I guess it'd make sense to just not allow AI libraries though?

Comment: Maybe disallowing AI-libraries could be a sensible idea, but I wouldn't know how to put this (ie. what is an AI-library and what is a regular library) formally. Though the standard (this does not mean that it's always the case or that you need to follow it) is to not disallow such things but rather discourage it. If I'd use a library which is not part of the standard libraries it would count as a different language, eg. *Python 3 + scikit* and in a perfect world less interesting submissions would be given less upvotes.

Comment: @BMO Rewrote it, does this look better?

Comment: I think the rules do look more structured and clean, but I still don't understand the challenge itself. Some questions I think the challenge should answer for which I can't find an answer might help: Are you requiring a program, function or a set of functions? What is the input and output format? What makes a solution valid? What is parsing string A to string B?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that golfed solutions might try to find some kind of weaknesses in your definitions to reduce the problem to the easiest way of solving it which might result in solutions that aren't very interesting from an AI perspective. This challenge might fit better [tag:test-battery] (you can set a byte-limit motivated by your own code if you want).

Comment: There are 2 critical pieces to this challenge that need to be clear before we can really make this post:  1. What are "Instructions"? 2. When an InstructionSet applies a string, what feedback does the AI get?

Comment: Finally, realize that rule #10 simply means I can iterate over every possible program until I land on one that works, no AI needed.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Did some clarifying randomness... better?

Comment: Not really.  [Let's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83756/the-tiniest-generic-evolutionary-ai)

Answer (score -2):

**Rotations Required**

Given input 2 values:

\$x >= 0\$ :Distance to travel (float)

\$r>0\$ :Radius of wheel (float)

Output the number of rotations required by the wheel to travel that distance.

*Constraints:*

Your code must not contain any digits.

You cannot use pi functions (math.pi)

Output must be an integer.(In case exact int is not obtained, floor it)
1.0 is not a valid output, it should be 1.

*Test Cases*

```
x       r    o/p
50      1    7
0       34   0
50      0.3  26
44      33   0
5.5     5.5  0
105     5    3
155     5    4
6.28318 1    1 #This signifies that pi was approximated to 3.1419
```

**Scoring:**

Score= No. of bytes+20/number of digits taken for pi after decimal point

If you have taken more than 10 digits:

Score= No. of bytes

Comment: "You cannot use pi functions" is an unobservable requirement, which is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228/20198).  You need some test cases.  The no-digits rule won't actually make this problem harder for most golflangs.

Comment: @NathanMerrill The latter is less problematic (and more objective) than the former.

Comment: Test cases are not strictly required, but it would make it easier to check if a solution is definitely incorrect.

Comment: Info: Adding constraints just "because the challenge is too easy" usually doesn't make it more interesting (unless the constraints are the main difficulty of the challenge, for example for radiation-hardened challenges)

Comment: I will add test cases. @NathanMerrill, there just shouldn't be any inbuilt functions that give pi directly is what I want to say.

Comment: @VedantKandoi I understand what you *want*, but we allow any language on this site, and it's impossible to define what a "pi-giving function" is to work for all possible languages.

Comment: Is there any other way I could word it then, as I don't want python, java etc. users to use math.pi or should I just remove it?

Comment: Also, since pi is in the formula, exact int will never be obtained, and if anyone uses approximate value of pi, they may get exact int at certain value or 1 less than desired answer. What can I add for this?

Comment: I changed the scoring method for the above issue, so should be okay now.

Comment: Why would the output be *floored*? Surely you should use ceiling so that the wheel is actually travelling that distance.

Comment: I was thinking of something like how many full rotations need to be completed.

Comment: "Not using a pi function" is a [non-observable program requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194), which is one of the things to avoid when writing a challenge. I don't see any way to fix this challenge: fundamentally what it's asking is too trivial to be interesting. My advice would be to delete the body of this answer and then delete the answer (to keep the sandbox tidy) and then to try to come up with a challenge which is inherently interesting enough that it doesn't need that kind of restriction.

Answer (score -2):

## Write a Self-Hosting Ouroboros: each quine produces the next quine AND its interpreter

*My meta-questions, please give feedback and/or add your own:*

- Too elaborate or long post?
- Rules too strict? Too lax?
- Not having a deadline: good or bad idea?

---

A [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) is a program that prints its own source code as output when it is run.

A [Self-Hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting) Quine (which is something I just made up, although I'm sure it exists already) is a quine that also produces an interpreter/compiler/emulator/whatever for itself (from now on I will just say "interpreter").

I believe this actually means that a lot of essential functionality must be "circularly defined" - for example, to print output, the interpreter must rely on the parent interpreter's ability to print output. So maybe we should call this a [Von Munchausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma) Quine?

An Ouroboros Program or Quine Relay is a quine that prints a different quine, which then prints yet another program, and so on, until the last quine produces the original quine. See [this famous example](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay%20Quine%20Relay) that cycles through over a hundred languages.

A Self-Hosting Ouroboros, then, is quine that produces a program in another language, and also produces an interpreter for that language. The interpreter should be in the current language, so that the next quine can immediately be run and produce the quine after that.

Tangent: obviously, the idea can also be extended to interpreter [multiquines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29#Multiquines) but that can be another challenge. Let's make Von Munchausen's Ouroboros first!

#### Rules

- The ouroboros must be able to make a complete cycle
- Score by `total quines in chain` / `shortest source code (in bytes) in the chain` (bytes to allow non-textual outputs)
- Empty quines and interpreters do not count - two character minimum
- Code-golf languages allowed
- No languages defined just for this challenge - no *"I define language x to always produce quine y in C plus the complete GCC compiler when fed any input"*-stuff please
- Quines must be valid code in their programming languages
- Interpreters that are partial language implementations are fine, however:

  - it must be able to run the quine, and produce the next quine (obviously).
  - it should be able to run *any other **correct** code* that is *limited to the same language subset¹*. No hyperfitting²!
  - for the sake of code golfing it *may* accept incorrect code that a normal interpreter should not (the quine is already restricted to *correct* code anyway)

### Clarifications

#### Yes, you can make a quine that produces itself and its own interpreter

Counts as a 1-chain ouroboros.

#### What would an "interpreter" for machine code be?

An [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator). Which of course needs some way to load a program and produce the output. You may define a fictional simplified, minimal hardware set-up to do so. For example: a (partial) Z80 emulator where:

- two hardware ports are connected to send output bytes to (one for interpreter, one for quine). Are those bytes interpreted as raw bytes/ASCI/UTF8 text/whatever? Up to you!
- the program is already loaded in memory, at whatever address is most convenient (quine too big to fit in the addressable memory space? Define an input port to scan bytes from I guess :P)
- the `PC` (program counter), and `SP` (stack pointer) registers initiate at whatever value is most convenient for creating a quine in Z80 opcode

Obviously, no set-ups with fictional ROM that just *happens* to contain a new quine, or stuff like that (even though this would be hard to *really* abuse, since that ROM would still need to be implemented in the emulator).

Am I seriously expecting anyone to create an emulator like this? No, but let's keep the possiblity open ([some stack machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) might be code golf-friendly enough for the challenge).

#### "Borrowing" snippets from each other is encouraged, but give accreditation and link to sources!

Because  we all really just want to see how long this can get, no? Besides, whatever you take probably has to be heavily modified to fit it in your existing ouroboros chain anyway. Sharing is caring, and accreditation is the decent thing to do.

#### No dead-line, nor will a winner be selected. Just make as long a chain as possible.

---

¹ You wrote an interpreter for a subset of Rust, but it doesn't feature the borrow checker? That is fine long as:

- it works with correct Rust code limited to the language subset
- it works with the quine itself
- the quine itself is correct rust code

² Example of what I do and do not consider hyperfitting: if your interpreter can deal with `for(var i; i < 10; i++) { a[i] = i; }` but crashes without the enclosing `{}` because it expects them to designate code blocks, that counts as a partial implementation. If `var` only expects `i`, or `<` only expects `i` and `10`? Hyperfitting. If `var` only accepts single letter names, and `<` only expects variables on the left and literals on the right? Probably hyperfitting but debatable.

Comment: What would the interpreter of a program written in machine code be?

Comment: How should we separate the quine output and the interpreter output?

Comment: @user202729: an emulator

Comment: @JoKing: hmm, good question. Two separate calls to whatever output method is chosen? (print or its equivalent)

Answer (score -2):

## Unicode encoder

Do [Invent your own Unicode 7.0.0 encoding (as efficient as possible)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40481/) with score 317754(the lowest possible score). Shortest encode+decode program win.

You can either write two programs doing encode and decode, or write one with argument/input method difference deciding whether it's encoding or decoding

```html
As you may know, the Unicode standard has room for 1,114,111 code points, and each assigned code point represents a glyph (character, emoji, etc.).

Most code points are not yet assigned.

Current Unicode implementations take a lot of space to encode all possible code points (UTF-32 takes 4 bytes per code point, UTF-16: 2 to 4 bytes, UTF-8: 1 to 4 bytes, etc.)


Task
-

Today, your task is to implement your own Unicode implementation, with the following rules:

- Write an encoder and a decoder in any language of your choice
- The encoder's input is a list of code points (as integers) and it outputs a list of bytes (as integers) corresponding to your encoding.
- The decoder does the opposite (bytes => code points)
- Your implementation has to cover all Unicode 7.0.0 assigned code points
- It has to stay backwards-compatible with ASCII, i.e. encode Basic latin characters (U+0000-U+007F) on one byte, with 0 as most significant bit.
- Encode all the other assigned code points in any form and any number of bytes you want, as long as there is no ambiguity (i.e. two code points or group of code points can't have the same encoding and vice versa)
- Your implementation doesn't have to cover UTF-16 surrogates (code points U+D800-U+DFFF) nor private use areas (U+E000-U+F8FF, U+F0000-U+10FFFF)
- Your encoding must be context-independant (i.e. not rely on previously encoded characters) and does NOT require self-synchronization (i.e. each byte doesn't have to infer where it's located in the encoding of a code point, like in UTF-8).

To sum up, here are the blocks that you have to cover, in JSON:

[
  [0x0000,0x007F], // Basic Latin
  [0x0080,0x00FF], // Latin-1 Supplement
  [0x0100,0x017F], // Latin Extended-A
  [0x0180,0x024F], // Latin Extended-B
  [0x0250,0x02AF], // IPA Extensions
  [0x02B0,0x02FF], // Spacing Modifier Letters
  [0x0300,0x036F], // Combining Diacritical Marks
  [0x0370,0x03FF], // Greek and Coptic
  [0x0400,0x04FF], // Cyrillic
  [0x0500,0x052F], // Cyrillic Supplement
  [0x0530,0x058F], // Armenian
  [0x0590,0x05FF], // Hebrew
  [0x0600,0x06FF], // Arabic
  [0x0700,0x074F], // Syriac
  [0x0750,0x077F], // Arabic Supplement
  [0x0780,0x07BF], // Thaana
  [0x07C0,0x07FF], // NKo
  [0x0800,0x083F], // Samaritan
  [0x0840,0x085F], // Mandaic
  [0x08A0,0x08FF], // Arabic Extended-A
  [0x0900,0x097F], // Devanagari
  [0x0980,0x09FF], // Bengali
  [0x0A00,0x0A7F], // Gurmukhi
  [0x0A80,0x0AFF], // Gujarati
  [0x0B00,0x0B7F], // Oriya
  [0x0B80,0x0BFF], // Tamil
  [0x0C00,0x0C7F], // Telugu
  [0x0C80,0x0CFF], // Kannada
  [0x0D00,0x0D7F], // Malayalam
  [0x0D80,0x0DFF], // Sinhala
  [0x0E00,0x0E7F], // Thai
  [0x0E80,0x0EFF], // Lao
  [0x0F00,0x0FFF], // Tibetan
  [0x1000,0x109F], // Myanmar
  [0x10A0,0x10FF], // Georgian
  [0x1100,0x11FF], // Hangul Jamo
  [0x1200,0x137F], // Ethiopic
  [0x1380,0x139F], // Ethiopic Supplement
  [0x13A0,0x13FF], // Cherokee
  [0x1400,0x167F], // Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics
  [0x1680,0x169F], // Ogham
  [0x16A0,0x16FF], // Runic
  [0x1700,0x171F], // Tagalog
  [0x1720,0x173F], // Hanunoo
  [0x1740,0x175F], // Buhid
  [0x1760,0x177F], // Tagbanwa
  [0x1780,0x17FF], // Khmer
  [0x1800,0x18AF], // Mongolian
  [0x18B0,0x18FF], // Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended
  [0x1900,0x194F], // Limbu
  [0x1950,0x197F], // Tai Le
  [0x1980,0x19DF], // New Tai Lue
  [0x19E0,0x19FF], // Khmer Symbols
  [0x1A00,0x1A1F], // Buginese
  [0x1A20,0x1AAF], // Tai Tham
  [0x1AB0,0x1AFF], // Combining Diacritical Marks Extended
  [0x1B00,0x1B7F], // Balinese
  [0x1B80,0x1BBF], // Sundanese
  [0x1BC0,0x1BFF], // Batak
  [0x1C00,0x1C4F], // Lepcha
  [0x1C50,0x1C7F], // Ol Chiki
  [0x1CC0,0x1CCF], // Sundanese Supplement
  [0x1CD0,0x1CFF], // Vedic Extensions
  [0x1D00,0x1D7F], // Phonetic Extensions
  [0x1D80,0x1DBF], // Phonetic Extensions Supplement
  [0x1DC0,0x1DFF], // Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement
  [0x1E00,0x1EFF], // Latin Extended Additional
  [0x1F00,0x1FFF], // Greek Extended
  [0x2000,0x206F], // General Punctuation
  [0x2070,0x209F], // Superscripts and Subscripts
  [0x20A0,0x20CF], // Currency Symbols
  [0x20D0,0x20FF], // Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols
  [0x2100,0x214F], // Letterlike Symbols
  [0x2150,0x218F], // Number Forms
  [0x2190,0x21FF], // Arrows
  [0x2200,0x22FF], // Mathematical Operators
  [0x2300,0x23FF], // Miscellaneous Technical
  [0x2400,0x243F], // Control Pictures
  [0x2440,0x245F], // Optical Character Recognition
  [0x2460,0x24FF], // Enclosed Alphanumerics
  [0x2500,0x257F], // Box Drawing
  [0x2580,0x259F], // Block Elements
  [0x25A0,0x25FF], // Geometric Shapes
  [0x2600,0x26FF], // Miscellaneous Symbols
  [0x2700,0x27BF], // Dingbats
  [0x27C0,0x27EF], // Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A
  [0x27F0,0x27FF], // Supplemental Arrows-A
  [0x2800,0x28FF], // Braille Patterns
  [0x2900,0x297F], // Supplemental Arrows-B
  [0x2980,0x29FF], // Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B
  [0x2A00,0x2AFF], // Supplemental Mathematical Operators
  [0x2B00,0x2BFF], // Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows
  [0x2C00,0x2C5F], // Glagolitic
  [0x2C60,0x2C7F], // Latin Extended-C
  [0x2C80,0x2CFF], // Coptic
  [0x2D00,0x2D2F], // Georgian Supplement
  [0x2D30,0x2D7F], // Tifinagh
  [0x2D80,0x2DDF], // Ethiopic Extended
  [0x2DE0,0x2DFF], // Cyrillic Extended-A
  [0x2E00,0x2E7F], // Supplemental Punctuation
  [0x2E80,0x2EFF], // CJK Radicals Supplement
  [0x2F00,0x2FDF], // Kangxi Radicals
  [0x2FF0,0x2FFF], // Ideographic Description Characters
  [0x3000,0x303F], // CJK Symbols and Punctuation
  [0x3040,0x309F], // Hiragana
  [0x30A0,0x30FF], // Katakana
  [0x3100,0x312F], // Bopomofo
  [0x3130,0x318F], // Hangul Compatibility Jamo
  [0x3190,0x319F], // Kanbun
  [0x31A0,0x31BF], // Bopomofo Extended
  [0x31C0,0x31EF], // CJK Strokes
  [0x31F0,0x31FF], // Katakana Phonetic Extensions
  [0x3200,0x32FF], // Enclosed CJK Letters and Months
  [0x3300,0x33FF], // CJK Compatibility
  [0x3400,0x4DBF], // CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
  [0x4DC0,0x4DFF], // Yijing Hexagram Symbols
  [0x4E00,0x9FFF], // CJK Unified Ideographs
  [0xA000,0xA48F], // Yi Syllables
  [0xA490,0xA4CF], // Yi Radicals
  [0xA4D0,0xA4FF], // Lisu
  [0xA500,0xA63F], // Vai
  [0xA640,0xA69F], // Cyrillic Extended-B
  [0xA6A0,0xA6FF], // Bamum
  [0xA700,0xA71F], // Modifier Tone Letters
  [0xA720,0xA7FF], // Latin Extended-D
  [0xA800,0xA82F], // Syloti Nagri
  [0xA830,0xA83F], // Common Indic Number Forms
  [0xA840,0xA87F], // Phags-pa
  [0xA880,0xA8DF], // Saurashtra
  [0xA8E0,0xA8FF], // Devanagari Extended
  [0xA900,0xA92F], // Kayah Li
  [0xA930,0xA95F], // Rejang
  [0xA960,0xA97F], // Hangul Jamo Extended-A
  [0xA980,0xA9DF], // Javanese
  [0xA9E0,0xA9FF], // Myanmar Extended-B
  [0xAA00,0xAA5F], // Cham
  [0xAA60,0xAA7F], // Myanmar Extended-A
  [0xAA80,0xAADF], // Tai Viet
  [0xAAE0,0xAAFF], // Meetei Mayek Extensions
  [0xAB00,0xAB2F], // Ethiopic Extended-A
  [0xAB30,0xAB6F], // Latin Extended-E
  [0xABC0,0xABFF], // Meetei Mayek
  [0xAC00,0xD7AF], // Hangul Syllables
  [0xD7B0,0xD7FF], // Hangul Jamo Extended-B
  [0xF900,0xFAFF], // CJK Compatibility Ideographs
  [0xFB00,0xFB4F], // Alphabetic Presentation Forms
  [0xFB50,0xFDFF], // Arabic Presentation Forms-A
  [0xFE00,0xFE0F], // Variation Selectors
  [0xFE10,0xFE1F], // Vertical Forms
  [0xFE20,0xFE2F], // Combining Half Marks
  [0xFE30,0xFE4F], // CJK Compatibility Forms
  [0xFE50,0xFE6F], // Small Form Variants
  [0xFE70,0xFEFF], // Arabic Presentation Forms-B
  [0xFF00,0xFFEF], // Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms
  [0xFFF0,0xFFFF], // Specials
  [0x10000,0x1007F], // Linear B Syllabary
  [0x10080,0x100FF], // Linear B Ideograms
  [0x10100,0x1013F], // Aegean Numbers
  [0x10140,0x1018F], // Ancient Greek Numbers
  [0x10190,0x101CF], // Ancient Symbols
  [0x101D0,0x101FF], // Phaistos Disc
  [0x10280,0x1029F], // Lycian
  [0x102A0,0x102DF], // Carian
  [0x102E0,0x102FF], // Coptic Epact Numbers
  [0x10300,0x1032F], // Old Italic
  [0x10330,0x1034F], // Gothic
  [0x10350,0x1037F], // Old Permic
  [0x10380,0x1039F], // Ugaritic
  [0x103A0,0x103DF], // Old Persian
  [0x10400,0x1044F], // Deseret
  [0x10450,0x1047F], // Shavian
  [0x10480,0x104AF], // Osmanya
  [0x10500,0x1052F], // Elbasan
  [0x10530,0x1056F], // Caucasian Albanian
  [0x10600,0x1077F], // Linear A
  [0x10800,0x1083F], // Cypriot Syllabary
  [0x10840,0x1085F], // Imperial Aramaic
  [0x10860,0x1087F], // Palmyrene
  [0x10880,0x108AF], // Nabataean
  [0x10900,0x1091F], // Phoenician
  [0x10920,0x1093F], // Lydian
  [0x10980,0x1099F], // Meroitic Hieroglyphs
  [0x109A0,0x109FF], // Meroitic Cursive
  [0x10A00,0x10A5F], // Kharoshthi
  [0x10A60,0x10A7F], // Old South Arabian
  [0x10A80,0x10A9F], // Old North Arabian
  [0x10AC0,0x10AFF], // Manichaean
  [0x10B00,0x10B3F], // Avestan
  [0x10B40,0x10B5F], // Inscriptional Parthian
  [0x10B60,0x10B7F], // Inscriptional Pahlavi
  [0x10B80,0x10BAF], // Psalter Pahlavi
  [0x10C00,0x10C4F], // Old Turkic
  [0x10E60,0x10E7F], // Rumi Numeral Symbols
  [0x11000,0x1107F], // Brahmi
  [0x11080,0x110CF], // Kaithi
  [0x110D0,0x110FF], // Sora Sompeng
  [0x11100,0x1114F], // Chakma
  [0x11150,0x1117F], // Mahajani
  [0x11180,0x111DF], // Sharada
  [0x111E0,0x111FF], // Sinhala Archaic Numbers
  [0x11200,0x1124F], // Khojki
  [0x112B0,0x112FF], // Khudawadi
  [0x11300,0x1137F], // Grantha
  [0x11480,0x114DF], // Tirhuta
  [0x11580,0x115FF], // Siddham
  [0x11600,0x1165F], // Modi
  [0x11680,0x116CF], // Takri
  [0x118A0,0x118FF], // Warang Citi
  [0x11AC0,0x11AFF], // Pau Cin Hau
  [0x12000,0x123FF], // Cuneiform
  [0x12400,0x1247F], // Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation
  [0x13000,0x1342F], // Egyptian Hieroglyphs
  [0x16800,0x16A3F], // Bamum Supplement
  [0x16A40,0x16A6F], // Mro
  [0x16AD0,0x16AFF], // Bassa Vah
  [0x16B00,0x16B8F], // Pahawh Hmong
  [0x16F00,0x16F9F], // Miao
  [0x1B000,0x1B0FF], // Kana Supplement
  [0x1BC00,0x1BC9F], // Duployan
  [0x1BCA0,0x1BCAF], // Shorthand Format Controls
  [0x1D000,0x1D0FF], // Byzantine Musical Symbols
  [0x1D100,0x1D1FF], // Musical Symbols
  [0x1D200,0x1D24F], // Ancient Greek Musical Notation
  [0x1D300,0x1D35F], // Tai Xuan Jing Symbols
  [0x1D360,0x1D37F], // Counting Rod Numerals
  [0x1D400,0x1D7FF], // Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols
  [0x1E800,0x1E8DF], // Mende Kikakui
  [0x1EE00,0x1EEFF], // Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols
  [0x1F000,0x1F02F], // Mahjong Tiles
  [0x1F030,0x1F09F], // Domino Tiles
  [0x1F0A0,0x1F0FF], // Playing Cards
  [0x1F100,0x1F1FF], // Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
  [0x1F200,0x1F2FF], // Enclosed Ideographic Supplement
  [0x1F300,0x1F5FF], // Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
  [0x1F600,0x1F64F], // Emoticons
  [0x1F650,0x1F67F], // Ornamental Dingbats
  [0x1F680,0x1F6FF], // Transport and Map Symbols
  [0x1F700,0x1F77F], // Alchemical Symbols
  [0x1F780,0x1F7FF], // Geometric Shapes Extended
  [0x1F800,0x1F8FF], // Supplemental Arrows-C
  [0x20000,0x2A6DF], // CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
  [0x2A700,0x2B73F], // CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C
  [0x2B740,0x2B81F], // CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D
  [0x2F800,0x2FA1F], // CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement
  [0xE0000,0xE007F], // Tags
  [0xE0100,0xE01EF]  // Variation Selectors Supplement
]

Total: 116,816 code points.

Scoring
--

Your score is the number of bytes that your encoder outputs when you feed it with all the 116,816 possible code points (in one time or separately).
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: I suppose 317754 is the optimal score, right?

Comment: @user202729 Yes if there are 116,816 code points

Comment: p.s. I think you should expand it while it is on the sandbox, just in case somebody don't understand the specification.

Answer (score -2):

## Forcing a kernel panic from a mountaintop

This is a thought resulting from a curious incident where C# code opening file apparently caused a BSOD. In the conclusion, it was due to a faulty driver, but from that a thought came up --- can one cause a kernel panic (or BSOD) using managed code exclusively?

### Why?

Typically in such environment, there are many compile-time and run-time checks that safeguard the code from doing something that would cause a kernel panic. For a mature managed environment, it *should* be impossible to cause the operating system to arrive into a bad state. In the case, though it was C# code, the fact that a faulty driver was involved breached the walled garden. But can we breach it from within?

### Rules

- The code must be managed in some fashion (e.g. Java, C#, VB.NET), and normally comes with both compile-time and run-time checks.
- The code should be running in a virtual machine or equivalent. (e.g. Java's JVM or .NET's AppDomain)
- The code should NOT rely on any external anything. No extern declarations, no networking, no dodgy APIs.
- The code should NOT use any construct which allow direct access to resources (e.g. `unsafe` in C#)
- The code should use only the native libraries & API available as part of its usual environment.
- Throwing an exception is not sufficient. To qualify, the code must result in a kernel panic.

### Criteria

Essentially a `code-golf` -

- The less code to kernel panic, the better
- The fewer dependencies the code uses to make it happen, the better
- The code that consistently causes a kernel panic is better than one that only does it sometimes

Comment: Is the code considered malicious code?

Comment: What is "managed code"?

Comment: While it can be used with malicious intent, the goal is more toward proving whether it's possible to unintentionally break through the walled garden. RE: "managed code" --- it might be a .NET-specific term but I use it in general sense to refer to any programming language that usually run in a some kind of sandbox -- I cited Java's JVM or .NET's AppDomain as such examples. Those usually enforce runtime checks in addition to compile-time checks to prevent doing stupid thing like passing a null pointer which usually is a trappable exception.

Answer (score -2):

Play [snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game_genre)) on a 50*50 grid. The snake will start at length 3, heading (2,0) with body (1,0) and (0,0). It shouldn't bump into wall or itself. There is always one food, which increases the length of snake by 1 when eaten.

Smallest amount of steps till there's no space to place food win. Flexible I/O, anyway it doesn't matter.

Vote on whether the food placer is transparent and allow food manipulation(Up for yes, down for no)

Comment: I think there are already quite a few snake challenges. You need to flesh out some more details here. How do you determine where the food will spawn? Will you be given some sampling of the game state (vision?) on each step?

Comment: @Beefster If "food placer is transparent and allow food manipulation", you just know how it spawns; If not, you get access to the location of current food

Comment: If food manip. is allowed, is the optimal score achievable by finding an Hamiltonian path starts with the snake?

Comment: @user202729 It depends on how strong the manipulation is

Answer (score -2):

[No-alphanumeric code exec](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178970/no-alphanumeric-code-exec)

Comment: -1 for `winning entries must be written in one of the 25 top languages`.

Comment: I'm trying to exclude golfing languages with that - this only seems like an interesting challenge to me if you don't allow languages where it's excessively trivial. Any suggestions for how to do that in a more permissive way or other thoughts about that goal?

Comment: actually, I think this will be quite difficult in many code golf languages as well, as they usually try to get brevity by cramming things into single letters and numbers. there are of course languages where it'll be excessively trivial, but that's fine, those solutions most likely just won't be upvoted.

Comment: Most golfing languages won't be able to pull sth. from the interconnected-webs afaik, so there's no real need to invent arbitrary restrictions to ban them.

Comment: Also "*but that's fine, those solutions most likely just won't be upvoted*" is too optimistic, usually it's the other way around :(

Comment: dang, good to know.

Answer (score -2):

## HTML-tac-toe

Build a one-player [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game with only HTML and CSS.

## Introduction

You can do just about anything with a fully-featured programming language, but how much can you accomplish on a Neopets petpage? Inspired by [http://www.neopets.com/~vuh](http://www.neopets.com/%7Evuh)

## Challenge

Build a one-player tic-tac-toe game with only HTML and CSS.

- Use no more than one file.
- GIFs (including animations), PNGs, and JPEGs are allowed.
- Flash, embedded scripts, iframes, and JavaScript are not allowed.
- It must work in the at least two standard browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE)

Inputs:
The player will click on a space when it's their turn to move there.

Outputs:
The page will show the current board state at all times.
The page will play an optimal move whenever the player moves, unless the game is over.

You're free to decide who starts and who has X or O.

## Scores

- -10 per image
- -1 per opening bracket or brace (`<` / `{` )

Brownie points for design, flair, and new tricks!

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> Click on the top left of an empty grid

Output:

> Grid shows my mark where I clicked and the opposite mark in the left middle or top middle.

Comment: I'd recommend against restricting languages, and against score bonuses too

Comment: @ASCII-only I can drop the bonuses without much consequence, but it's not a new challenge without a language or host restriction. Any suggestions?

Comment: True, but... language restrictions are pretty frowned upon

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You may want to check [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges) out, it certainly helped me when starting with writing my own challenges. Also, your post does not have a well-defined [objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It seems like it is [atomic code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/atomic-code-golf/info) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info) [1/2]

Comment: , but you will need to define how answers are scored (in this case lower is worse) and how ties are treated. Also why do you disallow GIFs but JPGs not? I know most will know, but maybe explain or at the very least link to somewhere where the rules for tic-tac-toe are explained. What counts as an X, what as an O? There are a lot of open question atm. [2/2]

Comment: JPGs are allowed. (That's the same format as JPEG, just a different extension.) I can change it to 'images', but I'm worried about some image format I don't know of that makes the challenge trivial.
More points, more better! That seems clear enough, but I can certainly spell it out. Are ties forbidden? Two entries with the same number of points seem equally good to me, but the first posted could be the winner.
If I link to tic-tac-toe rules, does that answer "What counts as an X, what as an O?" or are you asking something else?

Comment: "*Standard exceptions are allowed IF they work on Neopets.com.*" How do we know what works on Neopets.com? If we have to create accounts on a random third party site to test answers and know whether they're valid or not, the question should and probably will end up closed with a lot of downvotes.

Comment: This isn't very interesting in general. It essentially amounts to creating every possible layout of a tic-tac-toe board and linking them together with clever CSS and HTML hacks so it fits in 25 pages. I think it could be made a bit more interesting by making it atomic code golf scoring on the total number of html files used, lowest scores win rather than limiting the total number of pages.

Comment: @PeterTaylor very well, dropped that altogether

Comment: @Beefster The page I link to as the inspiration (http://www.neopets.com/~vuh) uses only one html file, and the source isn't too hard to understand, so perhaps I should link to the creator of the page instead, limit the solutions to one page, or both.

Comment: I highly suggest looking through current codegolf questions to see which are well-received by the community. This question seems highly arbitrary and leaves too much under-specified.

Answer (score -2):

## You can't tell me what to do!!!

#### Intentionally break as many coding conventions as possible while crafting a working Hello World

[coding-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-challenge) [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) [obfuscation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obfuscation)

For each language, a coding convention standard will be selected.
The following is the current list:

javascript -> [Google's Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

PHP -> [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

C++ -> [ISO C++ Style Guide](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)

Python -> [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

The maximum file length is 6000 characters. Any code beyond the first 6000 will not count towards broken conventions. (Using conventions that you have set to break after the 6000 point, however, will count against you.)

If you do not see your language, you may choose one of the most common coding standards for your language, and use that, and (hopefully) it will be noticed and added to the list. Each language is its own competition. (For example: If your code is in Ruby, you're not competing against C++ code)

This is the coding equivalent of an ugly baby contest, and pushes you to think outside the box (possibly way too far outside the box). The goal is to write a 'simple' Hello World program. However, you have to do it while breaking as many coding conventions as possible, and being as ugly as possible (but still working!)

The advantages of this puzzle are multi-purpose. This is to challenge the coder to separate long-standing habits (which generally follow coding conventions) from functionality - to encourage creativity. Further, it also serves as a reverse example to demonstrate when coding conventions are a help vs a hindrance.

Remember, ugly doesn't have to mean gibberish or unnecessarily long or poorly running. In fact, code length or runtime do not factor into the evaluation.

For example, you could write procedural code using only classes, use an eval() to declare constants, or use only use variable names using characters that have nothing to do with what the variable does, reverse indentation, or rely exclusively on gotos in an interpreted language. The only thing your code *has* to do is output "Hello World" to the command line or an equivalent.

Each answer should list and link to coding conventions it breaks and receives 1 point for each broken code convention (but instant total of zero points the code follows any coding convention it says its breaking). If a voter agrees it violates all the listed coding conventions, upvote the code that violates the most while still functioning. (Accidentally violating coding conventions, however, does not count. Each one violated coding convention must be documented and intentional.)

Note: For each coding convention taken on, it must be consistently broken across the entire program. Following the convention even once invalidates your entire code. Habits are your enemy. 
Further note: If you declare you're breaking a convention, you MUST break it. If it's not applicable, it doesn't count.

#### Alternate Scoring method:

Don't like the "call your shot and then try to make it" scoring method?
Do you have a readily available git functionality?
Does the coding convention have a convenient git-hook for code style enforcement?
Fear not, you have the option for an alternate scoring method:
 1. Write up your code.
 2. Run it through the git commit with the hook active.
 3. If your hook auto-changes code, commit it, and do step 4. If it gives you coding style errors and rejects the commit, count the errors; you get one point for each error and skip to step 5. If you break git due to the hook crashing, list the broken code enforcement, add 50 points, and try again with a different code-enforcement hook. (You CANNOT be an author or contributor to any git-hook before you test against it. This is considered cheating and will be disqualify you.)
 4. If your hook auto-changes code to fit style enforcement, do a git-diff between your code and the code it committed. Each change is one point.
 5. Total your points. List your points as an alternate score in your answer's header. List the code-enforcement hooks you tested it against.

I'm personally not a fan of this scoring method as it allows accidental points and becomes more like it's testing the enforcement hook rather than creative code style breaking, but some like the more computer-controlled scoring method... so there ya go.

*Sandbox Reminder: Sandbox is a place for **constructive** criticism. Saying, "I don't like it" or "I wouldn't do it" isn't constructive criticism. Last time I had this in the sandbox, most criticism was built on disliking the type of challenge, not actually building it properly. If you don't like the challenge concept, then just don't do it. If you have **legitimate** suggestions on how to **make the challenge better** then do so. I will do my best to address legitimate points.*

## Standard Example Answer format

---

## My Oh so wrong Hello world - PHP - Attempting 2 points

Breaking conventions in PSR-2:

- breaking "Opening braces for classes MUST go on the next line, and closing braces MUST go on the next line after the body."
- breaking "All PHP files MUST end with a single blank line."

--

```
<?php
class hiworld{public $printme = "Hello World"}
$hiworld = new hiworld;
echo $hiworld->$print; 
?>
```

---

## Alternate Example Answer format

---

## My Oh so wrong and totally fake Hello world - PHP - Alt.Points(53)

```
<?php
class hiworld{public $printme = "Hello World"}
$hiworld = new hiworld;
echo $hiworld->$print; 
?>
```

Attempted with:

50 pts: PSR-2 Foo's Enforcement Hook: Foo-Checker [http://foo.example.com] (Broke)

3 pts: PSR-2 Bar's Enforcement Hook: Bar-Checker [http://bar.example.com]

---

[Deleted Version](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: That just makes it better.

Comment: Hate as measured by votes, however, is a discrete value, and therefore objective.

Comment: While I disagree that pop cons need an objective criterion for voting (anything objectively measurable wouldn't need votes), pop cons are out of favour for that very reason. It is rare for a pop con to be welcomed.

Comment: @trichoplax Fair enough on that. I'll change encouragement to just be on coding style.

Comment: Related tag: [tag:code-trolling]. There's about a half dozen of these historically and they never did all that well. Anyone who has been around long enough: elaborate.

Comment: @Beefster Thanks for the tag suggestion. If it doesn't do well, that's fine, as long as it does at least okay.

Comment: The problem is mostly the [tag:popularity-contest] tag, which are very hard to do correctly. For example, how do you define `break as many coding conventions as possible`? How do you define convention, especially for esoteric languages where there *are* no conventions? The amount of conventions broken also depends on the poster's and viewer's standards, and is therefore not objective.

Comment: @JoKing I've updated it so it's more objective. Basically, it has to be defined somewhere according to someone's coding conventions. (And if you choose an esoteric language without conventions, there's no conventions to break, now are there?) Also, I've changed it away from popularity contest and given a more static format. Coding conventions must be found, linked, listed, and completely violated in order to count.

Comment: `If a voter agrees it violates all the listed coding conventions, upvote the code that violates the most while still functioning` is still subjective. All conventions are going to be subjective, e.g. `Proper indentation`, does that mean 4 spaces or a tab? One voter might think one way, and another might think another way. In general, I think you've chosen a very subjective winning criterion, and short of listing and defining the conventions yourself, it's not going to become objective again.

Comment: I've removed my downvote and the related comment.

Comment: The new scoring mechanism is still subjective, but a big improvement. What counts as a convention still seems like a grey area. Does it need to be from an official source, for some definition of official? Does it need to have been posted online prior to the posting of this challenge? Does it need to be stating that coders "must", "should", or something else?

Comment: One way to make this objective would be as a language specific challenge, for example with something like JSLint. That way your score is the number of complaints triggered when running it through the linter, and highest wins. Only being able to compete in one language doesn't seem ideal, but I mention it as an example in case someone can come up with a more inclusive approach.

Comment: Whatever scoring method is settled on, having no other limit to balance against means everyone can just include all the potential points. One way to create a trade off would be to include code length in the score. Perhaps violations divided by bytes.

Comment: "*Whatever makes you feel dirty for having put it through your keyboard*" and "*Each answer should list and link to coding conventions it breaks*" are mutually contradictory.

Comment: @trichoplax I do like your idea of counting linter complaints to make it more objective, and feel that's on the right track. Maybe bringing some code-cleanup program into it, and seeing how much work it has to do?

Comment: Even with the linked style guides, what is a convention? e.g. in the PHP one, there's the rule `lines SHOULD be 80 characters or less.` (emphasis not mine). Is a line longer than 80 characters count? There's quite a few more keywords like `OPTIONAL`, `MAY`, `RECOMMENDED`. Are these conventions?

Comment: I feel like this could work if one language was selected, with associated style guide/linter, and an objective scoring system made for that.  Otherwise, you're comparing a lot of apples and shoes.

Comment: @JoKing Yes, those would all be conventions. For the longer than 80 lines one, though, as mentioned if you break a convention once as one of your conventions, you have to CONSISTANTLY break it. So EVERY line would have to be longer than 80 characters for it to score.

Comment: @Spitemaster I honestly agree, but there's so many places in codegolf where it suggests -not- limiting to a single language, and I already feel the challenge won't get the most active sets of responses.

Comment: I know this probably isn't going anywhere, but the most 'official' python style guide is probably [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I actually do kind of want it to go somewhere. Still trying to figure out ways to improve it though.

Comment: @liljoshu You've got my upvote for what it's worth, though I agree this needs some improvements.

Comment: Something like https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172445/get-the-lowest-possible-pylint-score-within-128-bytes-of-python might be ok

Comment: I could see pulling similar with git code style enforcement hooks... not that I like doing it that way because it loses the 'called shot' aspect of it... but some may like it better to where more people are actually cool with it.

Answer (score -2):

## Bit flipper

Given a string s and a positive number n, return the string s with n random bits flipped. (A random number can be generated in any way, including pseudo-random number generators)

Example:

Before:

```
Hello World
```

After (n = 2, 2 bits flipped):

```
Hello wOrld
```

Comment: How exact are the bytes being 'flipped'? Are we changing the bits? Is the output deterministic? It doesn't look like you're modifying any specific bit of the byte, or reversing it, or doing bitwise negation.

Comment: @Riker well changing from uppercase to lowercase _is_ just xor 32. But they'rem saying _byte_ flipper not bit flipper which is a bit confusing

Comment: @Riker The bits are flipped

Comment: @JoKing No, that was an example because I didn’t wanted binary non-unicode characters in the post.

Comment: What is *n*? On the basis of what little is specified in the question, I would be tempted to write an implementation for n=0 which consists of the empty program in GolfScript...

Comment: @PeterTaylor A user defined count of how many bytes will be flipped

Comment: I think the confusion here is that "bytes" doesn't mean what you think it means. From the lone test case I think what you're trying to ask us is: given a string `s` and a number `n`, change the *case* of `n` random letters in `s` - would that be correct?

Comment: I assume case was just an example of bit 5 flipping. I'd recommend writing it like `Given a string s and a positive number n, return the string s with n random bits flipped`. Though from there you run into problems about invalid unicode sequences in the output

Comment: @JoKing I replaced with your example.

Comment: What do you mean by `Default n = 3`? Also, how should programs handle invalid unicode sequences?

Comment: @JoKing By default, n should be 3. And invalid unicode sequences should not be handled, and the data should be directly printed out to stdout or any output file.

Comment: When you say random, do you mean of our choice? pseudo-random? fetched from random.org?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl It is selected by the program.

Comment: @smileycreations15 It's gonna be hard to make that 100% random

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Not 100% random. A pseudo-random number or any random number generator.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Maybe you should add that to the question.

Answer (score -2):

## Best Mile Time

### Introduction

Your friend has been trying to improve his mile time on. Unfortunately, he isn't very good at keeping a steady pace and constantly speeds up and then slows down. He usually runs for many miles at a time and wants to choose the fastest mile of his run to determine his mile time.

Given your friend's distance versus time, determine his fastest mile time for a contiguous mile stretch.

### Input

A list of distances (in miles) sampled at an even interval.

### Output

The length of the smallest interval during which a distance of at least one mile was traveled.

### Rules

- You may assume that the the total distance traveled is at least 1 mile.
- The mile time must be for a continuous time interval.
- [Standard loop-holes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) apply.
- Please provide a link to test your code as well as an explanation.
- This is [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), so the program with the smallest asymptotic time complexity wins!
- Ties will be broken by fastest run time.

---

### Example

#### Python 3.7, O(n ^ 2)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHRboMwDEXf@Qq/NWgMQdt1bSX2IwhF7jBdGElRkk3s61lMt1I0aXk4Uuxr@8bpv/zbxWzGsaYGGnSenJdadSS90iRq5TyaV3LxMYJwlPFkP7FzUEBZTaHmYkGFBFg0ZxIdmbsqeIT8p/RX285aBQ@QJ7AsuZNPExu45cq2Cg3nq6rgpYB8WbCwmWLfk6mFUAm0cfxHeLKE79EUtuQ/rAGtjNDYiw71qUYYjjCUOY8dyqxK5s6hWRS8SWlQk5RQFLCSUqMyUq6ujm5GeVlZGl6apWvGhrFlPDF2jGfGnnFIIE8zxpqxZexmXLfe2@BE/PdhcTSO3w)

```
from typing import List


def fastest_mile_time(distances):
    """Determines the fastest mile time from a list of distances.

    Parameters
    ----------
    distances : List[float]
        The list of distances in miles.

    Returns
    -------
    int
        The length of the smallest interval during which at least one mile was traveled.
    """
    intervals = []
    for i in range(len(distances) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(distances)):
            if distances[j] - distances[i] >= 1:
                intervals.append((i, j))
                break

    return min(map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], intervals))
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman how's this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this is trivially O(n): keep two pointers into the list, advance them keeping them 1 mile apart, and keep track of the running minimum time. I'm downvoting, so ping me if I was mistaken or if this is updated so I can update my vote.

Comment: @lirtosiast O(n) is trivial. I just gave O(n ^ 2) as an example. However it isn't clear to me that O(n) is the lower bound. I think the fact that the sequence is monotonically increasing may be of some use (although I've yet to show that to be the case).

Comment: The optimal solution is O(n). You need to iterate two pointers through the entire list one time to ensure that you have found the minimum valid difference. The range of time this will take ranges from Ω(n) to O(2n) in the optimized case. for(i=j=0;j<length;i++){for(;array[j]-array[i]<1&&j<length;j++){}minTime=min(minTime , j-i)}

Comment: Consider a list where every element at even index 2n is n, and every element at index 2n+1 is either n+.5 or n+1. If there is an integer at an odd index, the fastest mile time is 1, otherwise it's 2. But we have no way of determining this without reading all n/2 odd indices.

Comment: @lirtosiast +1 thanks for such a clear example!

Answer (score -2):

### Produce a self-reproducing data structure

Write the shortest code to produce a self-reproducing list, dictionary, array, and so on and so forth. That is, when you index **any one of the logically-available items** that belongs to the resulting data structure that you have produced, you get the same data structure when you compare the equality between the data structure before you indexed and the data structure after you indexed.

- In order to verify your code with automatically-provided constructions in programming languages, you should pick an operator that compares whether two values are equal (or does type-comparisons, if available).
- If your language does not provide an equality operator, you should simulate an equality operator yourself using operators like `-` or other operators that do the job of comparing values (as in *Acc!*, where an explicit comparison operator is not provided.)

### Example

This is an example of a validity/equality test of a possible solution in a Python REPL (when you have already produced a list, namely `list`, where it produces itself at its 0th item). This test simply compares the equality between the non-indexed list and the indexed list:

```
>>> list
[[...]]
>>> list[0]
[[...]]
>>> list==list[0]
True
```

However, if the result of the last line (the equality comparison) is not a truthy value in your language (for example `False` and `0` in Python), then your answer is invalid and should be improved.

### Rules

- Your program does not have to take input; neither does it have to explicitly output the data structure. However, your resulting data structure has to be accessible in some way.
- This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer will win.
- No standard loopholes, please.
- *In this challenge, the values on both operands in the equality check should have the same type.*
- **Your code (both your testing code and your producing code) should not produce any errors; any outputs to stderr are considered non-truthy values and demonstrates that your code is invalid.**

  ---

  [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

Comment: What does "*compare it*" mean? There are many many types of comparison one can perform, and they don't necessarily give the same result for the same values.

Comment: @A__ For JavaScript, is it `==` or `===`? Either way, people will be angry.

Comment: @A__ Because either the challenge is trivial (`['']`) or you're arbitrarily restricting a language. Work on your definition of "equality operator".

Comment: @A__ So, basically, you want `(x=[])[0]=x`? No clever tricks? Just a bog-standard recursive data structure? (Though, it might be interesting in languages where those aren't allowed.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 In fact, your program is a clever trick that I have not thought of. Mine is 13 bytes, yours is 11 bytes. Yes, what I want is a bog-standard recursive data structure, as long as it is not a duplicate of another question. (My program is ```a=[];a.push(a)```)

Comment: @U10-Forward 0 bytes

Comment: @tjjfvi I thought about that one, but I didn't think it'd be syntactically valid. It does, however, work.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 How do you know which language?

Comment: @tjjfvi I just assumed it was a language where the "null" / "undefined" singleton was indexable, returning the very same value.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No, JS: `window.window === window` :)

Comment: @tjjfvi I read the challenge differently to you. I thought it meant "any one of the logically-available items". By this rule, `(x={}).x=x` is the shortest I can think of, other than the trivial case.

Comment: @tjjfvi Well i do it in Python so no such a thing called 0 bytes in python

Comment: Alternative: ```window["window"]===window```

Answer (score -2):

## Recursive Sum Up The Digits

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer)

Produce the shortest code that sums up all the digits in a number, and after if it still has more than one digit, sum it up again and again until it's with one digit, example: `987` would become `6` since `9 + 8 + 7` is `24`, whereas `2 + 4` is `6`.

Comment: I have the feeling I've seen this challenge before, but I'm unable to find it. It could be that I'm confusing it with two similar loose challenges, since there are more challenges where we continue doing something until a single digit remains, and there are also loads of challenges summing the digits of an integer. I'm not 100% sure anymore whether there is already one with both combined.

Comment: This is just "Given `n` output `n % 9`".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, now I remember where I've seen it before: here in the sandbox, and you (or someone else) made that same comment. :)

Comment: Isnt this just a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1775/87923?

Comment: @EdgyNerd It's related, but not a dupe. That challenge takes multiple integers as input simultaneously, instead of a single input. And it outputs the amount of iterations for each of those integers to become a single digit, instead of the resulting digit itself. In addition, it has rather cumbersome output-format.. So that challenge would result in `987 2` for input `[987]`. The core part of both challenges is the same though: continue summing the digits of an integer until a single digit remains.

Answer (score -2):

## Make it improbable... BUT NOT IMPOSSIBLE

You must make a program that outputs truly once in a while. However, making it have output falsy all the time is not acceptable.

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- You may use any of accepted I/O formats.
- Your program must be possible to output a truly value.
- When not outputting a truly value, you may either output a falsy value or not output anything at all.
- You may output two or more values, however if it contains a truly value, then the output is considered truly.
- The probability of outputting a truly value must be at most 1/2.
- Your program must not take/use an input.
- Using non-deterministic but non-random(Such as getting the time) is prohibited. However, if date etc. is used in the builtin random function, it is allowed.
- The program must theoretically always terminate or stop outputting anything.
- You may assume that you have a fast enough computer and large enough memory.
- Your program should not be affected by raising the maximum value of a data type. You may still use unaffected constants.
- Data types must be following its spec: ie. for an unbounded arbituary precision integer type, you may assume that it can go as high as you want(but you are not allowed to increment until an error as in the rule above), but a double-precision floating-point format still has 22-bit fraction and 8-bit exponent.
- Score is calculated as: P<sup>l<sup>-1.5</sup></sup>l, where P is the probability and l is the byte length.

### Example(s)

```
JavaScript
alert(Math.random()<0.1)
P=0.1, l=24 => Score=23.534
```

The lowest score wins!

Comment: So is it acceptable for just a program that always outputs truly? You need to define improbable. (I assume this probability must be at least lest than 1/2.) Providing a few examples will be helpful. So is there only output and no input? In addition, you need an objective winning criterion, which is a criterion that posts for this challenge will need to comply in order for it to be a valid answer. (Usually this criterion is making the source code shortest.)

Comment: Sorry, I posted this incomplete.

Comment: I don't think your scoring method works particularly well, unless I'm making an error. For any \$ l > 1 \$ your score cannot be less than 1. Achieving a score arbitrarily close to 1 is relatively easy. So the only way to beat that is to have a one or zero byte solution. It is easy to make the probability increase exponentially with linear code additions. It might be necessary to penalise length massively, like \$ P \times e^{l!} \$, to avoid similar problems.

Comment: I see. I guess P^l^k is too penalizing but Pk or P*e^k is too forgiving. P*e^l! looks simple enough but is is the middle so it may work.

Comment: The problem with any of scoring methods for this challenge is that it is possible for any increasing computable function f, a program with length l can have P around 1/f(l). The only non-broken formula could be uncomputable, i.e. P/BB(l), where BB is the busy beaver function.

Answer (score -2):

## I reverse the source code, you keep the output

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout)

*Yet another blatant [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193315/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-reverse-the-input) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193021/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-input) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558/i-double-the-source-you-double-the-output). Go upvote those!*

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program/function that outputs/returns its own output. The tricky part is that if I reverse your source code, the output must be preserved.

## Examples

Let's say your code is `ABC` and the corresponding output is `XYZ`. If I run `CBA`, the output must **also** be `XYZ`

Comment: What's to prevent a trivial solution of just `1` in many (many) languages?

Comment: Or trivial comment abuse?

Comment: @JL2210 This works in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193315/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-reverse-the-input `print("ABC")#("ABC")tnirp`

Comment: @AdmBorkBork This works in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193315/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-reverse-the-input too: 1 is the reverse of 1

Comment: And to both of you: why did these not stop that code golf becoming a challenge?

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be a challenge. I just wanted to point out that this is trivial in many languages. And for what it's worth, I downvoted the challenge you linked for the same reason.

Comment: @gadzooks02 That challenge requires you to reverse the input. The input can be anything in that challenge.

Comment: @JL2210 Ah yes. Would preserve the _input_ work better?

Comment: No, then it would be trivial in Bash and BrainFuck and C and, well, you get the point.

Comment: @JL2210 Yes, OK. Do I need to do something if I've decided against a challenge? Delete the post?

Comment: No idea. Read over the guidelines, they might help.

Answer (score -2):

### print 1000 digits of \$\pi\$ base 3

The [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196135) was on hold for "unclear what you're asking". Really? What was the real reason?

No input. We need to *compute* and print the values of [\$\pi\$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi.html) and [Euler constant \$\gamma\$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)
to \$1000\$ digits after decimal point
in base \$3\$ with digits \$-1,0,1\$ represented as `-`,`0`,`+` respectively.

For \$\pi\$ output is likely starts with [`+0.0++-+++-000-0++-++0+-++++++00--++`](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoMgFET3fgU7QC9G6q6JX0JYYKX1tuURxAS/3mrbxWxmcs7ELc/BX/YdXQwpE2fyXJUh2Wm9WfY2bpwMKYDX0ijm0DMlJHQgNbzsNvx3fzXjwk60jSiW1TFT93UdyT0kYiAS9KRw4c8SOQfkGpLxD8t6EP0RyUFpXsWEPjNK22c4nqjoGqpQdbqR@qvCn4jv@wc).
\$\pi\$ can be computed as series of \$\tan^{-1}\$, \$\gamma\$ -- like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129777/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-algorithm-for-estimating-eulers-constant-g), or any other method will do if fast enough to provide needed accuracy for at most \$60\$ seconds for both numbers.

Storing or using entire pre-computed values are *forbidden*.
One may though use wolframalpha regular-base-3 values *for checking* their output -- for [\$\pi\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pi+in+base+3) and [\$\gamma\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EulerGamma+in+base+3) (hit "More digits" some times to get \$1000\$).

Scoring method is code-golf, but TIO should run at most \$60\$ seconds.
Good luck. Please fell free to improve this post.

Comment: "Storing or using entire pre-computed values are forbidden" is definitely one source of unclarity. What amount of pre-computation could be done? All but the last digit? All but two? Further there doesn't seem to be any reason to ask for two numbers, nor is there a on-site way to check the results. You shouldn't make your answerers have to go to an external site to verify their submission.

Answer (score -2):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

## Introduction

As programming languages <s>reproduce</s> are created, documentation is even more important for programmers. Your task is simple: output the esolangs.org documentation for your programming language.

With wikis being wikis, languages are heavily penalized in this challenge for being used often and for being interesting to write about, the goal here is to draw attention to languages that may not get utilized otherwise.

## Challenge

For this task, you will need to output the source for the article on esolangs.org for your language, with *greater than or equal to 95% accuracy*. Your score is your program length in bytes, as in other challenges.

Languages not on [this multi-page list of languages](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Languages) as of the time of this posting are ineligible.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Inputs

None

### Output

The source (as of this challenge being posted), for the esolangs wiki page for your language, with at least 95% accuracy.

## Example

*Language: ///*

Output:

> {{featured language}}
> '''///''' (pronounced "slashes") is a minimalist [[Turing-complete]] esoteric programming language, invented by Tanner Swett ([[User:Ihope127]]) in 2006 based on [[wikipedia:sed|the "s/foo/bar/" notation that everybody seemed to be using in IRC]]. The only operation is repeated string substitution, using the syntax <code>/''pattern''/''replacement''/</code>. Despite its extreme simplicity – there isn't even an obvious way to create a loop – it was proved [[Turing-complete]] by [[Ørjan Johansen]] in 2009, who created [[#Bitwise Cyclic Tag interpreter|an interpreter]] for the Turing-complete language [[Bitwise Cyclic Tag]].
> ...

Comment: -1: Interesting idea, but I don't think it can work as a challenge. I'm not convinced that [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]-ing a volatile data source is a good idea. What happens if the page is edited two weeks from now?

Comment: Loophole. I blanked the esolangs.org documentation of my language. Therefore I can output nothing to achieve my goal.

Comment: @A̲̲ nope, you have to output what it was at the time of posting

Comment: Obviously, you blank the page and then post before it gets fixed.

Answer (score -2):

## Finite Elements from Scratch

---

## Background

"The finite element method (FEM), is a numerical method for solving problems of engineering and mathematical physics." -Wikipedia

One of the elementary formulations of fem in structural engineering is the truss. They are very basic, but have a lot of utility.

[image]

When one designs a truss, especially in the preliminary stages some assumptions are usually made to simplify the procedure. For instance, members are assumed to carry only tension or compression load. This means that we can only load the truss at the nodals points. Depending on how the connection is designed and detailed, these assumptions can be quite close to how the structure actually will behave in the real world.

So, what's so special about having a member with only axial loading? Well, there's a property of the material itself we can take advantage of. Most materials have a property of 'linear elasticity' when the material is stretched or compressed a very small amount. A material like steel is quite ductile, and so this range of linear elasticiticy is quite large, as compared to something like ceramics. This means if we push or pull on some steel with a small force, it will displace a proportional amount. If we double our applied force, its displacement will double as well. Also if we release our force, the material will go back to its original configuration. So as long as we deform the material elastically, we won't waste any energy deforming it plastically.

If you have ever taken a physics class, you may know that a spring has these exact same properties. Therefore, we can idealize all the members in our truss as just simple springs.

---

### Building up to direct stiffness method

A zero dimensional spring equation looks like this.
$$
K \cdot u = F
$$
This relates the force required to any deformation of the spring. The force and deformation are linearly proportional by \$K\$, the spring constant. The constant \$K\$ has units of [force/distance] e.g. [pounds/in] or [kilograms/meter]. For example, if \$K = 50 lb/in\$, it would take \$50lb\$ of force to displace the spring \$1\$ inch, and \$100lb\$ to displace the spring \$2\$ inches. The stiffness in our truss members is similar:

$$
K = \frac{EA}{L}
$$

\$E\$ is Young's Modulus, \$A\$ is the cross sectional area, and \$L\$ is the length of the bar. The only scary thing here is probably \$E\$, but it's not too crazy. It's kind of like stiffness, but it's normalized. Instead of [force/distance] we have [stress/strain]. Stress is like the normalized force, it's the amount of force over the area of the element. Strain is like the normalized displacement, it's calculated by (change in length/original length) or percent elongation.

Let's develop this a bit more and put it in matrix form. This will allow us to relate the force on one side of the bar to force on the other.

$$
\frac{EA}{L}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_1 \\
f_2 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Now we have our one dimensional spring equation. Instead of a single displacement, we have a displacement vector. We can displace both sides of the spring independently and find what the resultant forces on each side will be.

Examples:

Displace the right node 1 unit to the right
$$
\frac{EA}{L}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_1 \\
f_2 \\
\end{array}\right]\\
f_1 = \frac{-E A}{L}, f_2 = \frac{E A}{L}
$$

This makes sense, because if we displace the right side by a unit, we need a force in the equal and opposite direction on the left side to not drag that side along.

Displace both nodes \$1\$ unit to the right
$$
\frac{EA}{L}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_1 \\
f_2 \\
\end{array}\right]\\
f_1 = 0, f_2 = 0
$$

This makes sense, because if we displace both sides at the same time, the distance between them does not change. It would be as if we just translated the spring across the table and did not strech it. We don't need some force holding it in a deformed configuration.

That's cool, but one dimensional structures are lame. I want a two dimensional structure to build a bridge! Well, it's not that much more difficult. We just need to add a \$y\$ degree of freedom (dof) on each side of the spring. We can also couple our \$x\$ and \$y\$ dofs into one angle from the \$+x\$ direction to simplify our matrix. And so with some magic (rotational matrix) we can get the following:

### Step 1 - Local Stiffnes Matrix

[image]

This is our local stiffness matrix, also known as \$K^e\$. It has all the same properties as our one dimensional stiffness matrix, but it takes into account \$(x,y)\$ displacements at each side of the spring. This gives us a total of four degrees of freedom.

You may begin to see how powerfull this method can be. We can now iterate through all of our elements and just calculate the angle and length from its nodes. This will give us \$i\$ local stiffness matrices, where \$i\$ is the number of elements. For example if we have \$3\$ elements in our truss, we can calculate our \$3\$ local matrices for each element.

Let's go through an example.

[image]

If we calcualted the local stiffness matrices for the figure above (\$EA = 1\$, \$L(1,2)=1\$), you would find:
$$
\hspace{50pt}\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\end{array} \\
K(1) = 
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1  & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0  & 0 & 0  & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1  & 0\\
0  & 0 & 0  & 0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
\hspace{50pt}\begin{array}{cccc}3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\\end{array} \\
K(2) = 
\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1  & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
\hspace{50pt}\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 5 & 6\\\end{array} \\
K(3) = 
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
5 \\
6 \\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0.64  & 0.48 & -0.64 & -0.48\\
0.48  & 0.36 & -0.48 & -0.36\\
-0.64 & -0.48 & 0.64 & 0.48\\
-0.48 & -0.36 & 0.48 & 0.36\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Where the numbers outside the array correspond to the global matrix indicies.

### Step 2 - Assemble local matrices into the global matrix

These local matricies are uncoupled, and so they don't really tell us much about the global system of the truss, or how to solve for the displacements with given forces. However, we can do something called matrix assembly to put them all into one big global stiffness matrix. This will couple all of our local element equations so we can solve our system of equations.

We do this by matching the local degrees of freedom to our global degrees of freedom, then add our local to our global matrix.

Since our global truss has 3 nodes and each node has \$2\$ dofs \$(x,y)\$, our global matricies are of size 6. \$K \in \mathbb R^{6 \times 6}, F \in \mathbb R^{6 \times 1}, u \in \mathbb R^{6 \times 1}\$. If we layed out the dof number for each row/column of our stiffness matrix we would get the following:

$$
\hspace{35pt}\begin{array}{cccccc}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\\end{array} \\
K = 
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

From step 1, the global dofs of \$k(1)\$ were \$1,2,3,4\$. This means we just add them index by index into our global stiffness matrix.

$$
\hspace{35pt}\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\end{array} \\
k(1) = 
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
k_{11} & k_{12}  & k_{13} & k_{14}\\
k_{21} & k_{22}  & k_{23} & k_{24}\\
k_{31} & k_{32}  & k_{33} & k_{34}\\
k_{41} & k_{42}  & k_{43} & k_{44}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

If we match up the indicies, we can just add:
$$
K_{11} += k_{11}\\
K_{12} += k_{12}\\
K_{13} += k_{13}\\
K_{14} += k_{14}\\
K_{21} += k_{21}\\
...
$$

[image]

We can see if we do this for all three elements, we can match up where they will go in the global matrix with colors. This is shown in the figure below.

[image]

### Step 3 - Add bounds on the stiffness matrix, and modify the force vector

[image]

We are almost done! But there is one final important step. If we were given an arbitrary force vector and tried to find the displacements, our truss would just fly away to infinity. This is because there are no boundary conditions! There is nothing yet holding on to it, resisting the forces. But guess what? There's another neat trick we can use. This will keep everything in matrix form and give us the answers we want when we solve our system of equations.

All we do is remove the influence of the node on the force vector. For this example, we will assume the constraint on dof1 is set to \$g\$.

For the general case, we just set \$dof1 = g\$ in the force vector, and subtract g* the column of \$K\$ with dof1 = 0. If \$g=0\$, we just need to set \$dof1 = 0\$ in the force vector.

$$
F = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
F_1\\
F_2\\
F_3\\
\vdots\\
F_n\\
\end{array}\right] \Rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{c}
g\\
F_2\\
F_3\\
\vdots\\
F_n\\
\end{array}\right] - g
\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
K_{21}\\
K_{31}\\
\vdots\\
K_{n1}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Then we just restrain our stiffness matrix. This can be done by zeroing out the row and column of \$dof1\$, then setting \$(dof1,dof1)=1\$ as shown below.

$$
K = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
K_{11}   & K_{12}   & \cdots & K_{1n}\\
K_{21}   & K_{22}   & \cdots & K_{2n}\\
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
K_{n1}   & K_{n2}   & \cdots & K_{nn}\\
\end{array}\right] \Rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1   & 0    & \cdots & 0\\
0   & K_{22}   & \cdots & K_{2n}\\
\vdots  & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
0   & K_{n2}   & \cdots & K_{nn}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

### Step 4 - Solve with linear algebra

Now we are finally back to our equation of a spring. However, in this case each variable below is an array or vector of size \$n\$, where \$n\$ is the number of \$nodes \times 2\$.

$$
\mathbf{K} \cdot \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{F}
$$

We can simply solve this system of equations by taking the inverse of the stiffness matrix. This gives us:

$$
\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{K}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{F}
$$

This can be easily solved by a computer. For example Python:

```
    u = np.linalg.solve(K, F)
```

---

## Rules

- Input data type can for the most part be changed for your needs. However, it should be human-readable, or at least reasonable to be able to change the input for a new structure easily.

Example input

```
E = .
A = .
nodes = [., ., ...]
elements = [., ., ...]
forces = [., ., ...]
bounds = [., ., ...]
```

Example output

```
[., ., ...]
```

- Output can be in any form, as long as it's in order of dof.
- Inbuilt FEM functions not allowed. You must construct and assemble your matrices yourself. Inbuilt linear algebra is fine.

## Test Cases

From UNM example in references:

```
E = 29500
A = 1
nodes = [[0,0],[40,0],[40,30],[0,30]]
elements = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[3,4]]
forces = [[0,0],[20,0],[0,-25],[0,0]]
bounds = [[0,0],[None,0],[None,None],[0,0]]
```

Output:

```
[0.0 0.0 0.027 0.0 0.006 -0.022 0.0 0.0]
```

Large Truss Input:

```
E = 29000
A = 25
nodes = [[0,0],[100,0],[200,0],[300,0],[0,100],[100,100],[200,100],[300,100],[400,100]]
elements = [[1,2],[1,5],[1,6],[2,3],[2,6],[2,7],[3,4],[3,7],[3,8],[4,8],[4,9],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,9]]
forces = [[0,-10],[0,-10],[0,-10],[0,-10],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,-10]]
bounds = [[0,0],[None,None],[None,None],[None,None],[-0.01,0],[None,None],[None,None],[None,None],[None,None]]
```

Output:

```
[ 0.     0.    -0.008 -0.025 -0.012 -0.061 -0.014 -0.1   -0.01   0.     0.004 -0.019  0.012 -0.057  0.016 -0.098  0.018 -0.136]
```

Here is what the geometry and displacement looks like for the test cases so you can visualize it.

[image]

[image]

---

## References

Here are some references that may be useful if you are looking for some more in-depth information.

http://www.unm.edu/~bgreen/ME360/Finite%20Element%20Truss.pdf

https://engineering.purdue.edu/~aprakas/CE474/CE474-Ch5-StiffnessMethod.pdf

http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/cee421/truss-method.pdf

http://ocw.ump.edu.my/pluginfile.php/9806/mod_resource/content/2/7_Plane_Truss_Example.pdf

https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/105105109/pdf/m4l24.pdf

And lastly, here is some working python 3 code that I wrote. It should lay out all the steps cleanly.

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt,sin,cos,acos

def ex_unm():
    """Example - Verification from UNM"""
    print("Example UNM")
    # Material Properties
    E = 29500 # (units = ksi)
    A = 1 # (units = in^2)
    # Node locations (units = in)
    nodes = {1:(0,0), 2:(40,0), 3:(40,30), 4:(0,30)}
    # Element connections
    elements = {1:(1,2), 2:(3,2), 3:(1,3), 4:(4,3)}
    # Nodal forces (units = kips)
    forces = {2:(20,0), 3:(0,-25)}
    # Nodal Boundaries (units = in)
    bounds = {1:{'x':0,'y':0},2:{'y':0},4:{'x':0,'y':0}}
    # Run Analysis
    displacements = analyze(E,A,nodes,elements,forces,bounds)
    for i,disp in enumerate(displacements):
        print("Node {},{}: {}".format(int(i/2)+1,['x','y'][i%2],round(disp,5)))

    plot_truss(nodes, elements, displacements, 200)

def ex_big_boi():
    """Example - Large Truss"""
    print("Example BIG BOI")
    # Material Properties
    E = 29000 # (units = ksi)
    A = 25 # (units = in^2)
    # Node locations (units = in)
    nodes = {1:(0,0), 2:(100,0), 3:(200,0), 4:(300,0),
        5:(0,100), 6:(100,100), 7:(200,100), 8:(300,100), 9:(400,100)}
    # Element connections
    elements = {1:(1,2), 2:(1,5), 3:(1,6),
        4:(2,3), 5:(2,6), 6:(2,7),
        7:(3,4), 8:(3,7), 9:(3,8),
        10:(4,8), 11:(4,9),
        12:(5,6), 13:(6,7), 14:(7,8), 15:(8,9)}
    # Nodal forces (units = kips)
    forces = {1:(0,-10), 2:(0,-10), 3:(0,-10), 4:(0,-10), 9:(0,-10)}
    # Nodal Boundaries (units = in)
    bounds = {1:{'x':0,'y':0}, 5:{'x':-0.01,'y':0}}
    #bounds = {1:{'x':0,'y':0}, 5:{'x':0,'y':0}}
    # Run Analysis
    displacements = analyze(E,A,nodes,elements,forces,bounds)
    for i,disp in enumerate(displacements):
        print("Node {},{}: {}".format(int(i/2)+1,['x','y'][i%2],round(disp,5)))

    plot_truss(nodes, elements, displacements, 500)


"""Visualization, not really needed but may be good to see"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_truss(nodes, elements, u, scale):
    """A very simple plot to show geometry and displacements of nodes"""
    x = [coords[0] for node,coords in nodes.items()]
    y = [coords[1] for node,coords in nodes.items()]
    ux = x + u[::2] * scale
    uy = y + u[1::2]* scale

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    # Plot original Points
    ax.plot(x,y,'o',color=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
    # Plot original Elements (Theres probably a better way to do this)
    for element,eleNodes in elements.items():
        ex = [x[i-1] for i in eleNodes]
        ey = [y[i-1] for i in eleNodes]
        ax.plot(ex,ey,color=(0.5,0.5,0.5))

    # Plot displaced Points
    ax.plot(ux,uy,'o',color=(0,0,1))
    # Plot displaced Elements (Theres probably a better way to do this)
    for element,eleNodes in elements.items():
        ex = [ux[i-1] for i in eleNodes]
        ey = [uy[i-1] for i in eleNodes]
        ax.plot(ex,ey,color=(0,0,1))

    # Make plot have same xy scale
    ax.axis('equal')
    #fig.tight_layout()
    ax.set_title("Truss Geometry and Displacement, Scale = {}".format(scale))







def analyze(E, A, nodes, elements, forces, bounds):
    """Analyze a given system and return the nodal displacements"""
    # Assemble global matricies
    K = gen_global_K(E,A,nodes,elements)
    F = gen_global_F(nodes,forces)
    # Add bounds to matricies
    #F = restrain_stiffness(K, F, bounds)
    restrain_stiffness(K, F, bounds)
    # Solve K*u=F -> u=K^-1*F
    u = np.linalg.solve(K, F)
    # return the nodal displacements
    return u

def gen_global_K(E, A, nodes, elements):
    """Generate the Global stiffness Matrix"""
    # Initialize Global Stiffness Matrix
    size = len(nodes)*2
    K = np.zeros([size,size])

    # Itterate through each element and add its local stiffness to global stiffness
    for element,(node_1,node_2) in elements.items():
        node_1_xy = nodes[node_1]
        node_2_xy = nodes[node_2]
        # Element length
        L = sqrt((node_2_xy[0]-node_1_xy[0])**2 + (node_2_xy[1]-node_1_xy[1])**2)
        # Get this element's local stiffness roated into global plane
        K_local = (E*A/L) * gen_local_K(node_1_xy, node_2_xy)
        # Assemble local matrix into global 
        assemble(K, K_local, node_1, node_2)
    return K

def gen_local_K(n1, n2):
    """Create a local stiffness matrix from two nodes' angle"""
    angle = gen_angle(n1,n2)
    c  = cos(angle)**2
    s  = sin(angle)**2
    cs = cos(angle) * sin(angle)
    # Create the local K matrix
    K_local = np.array([[ c , cs,-c ,-cs],
                        [ cs, s ,-cs,-s ],
                        [-c ,-cs, c , cs],
                        [-cs,-s , cs, s ]])
    return K_local

def gen_angle(n1, n2):
    """Find angle between two nodes and +x axis"""
    v1 = np.array([n2[0]-n1[0],n2[1]-n1[1]])
    v2 = np.array([1,0])
    return acos(np.dot(v1,v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2)))

def assemble(K, K_local, n1, n2):
    """Assemble a local element stiffness matrix into the global stiffness"""
    # Degrees of freedom of our local element
    dofs = [2*(n1-1), 2*(n1-1)+1, 2*(n2-1), 2*(n2-1)+1]
    # Go element by element to add matrix
    for i_local,i_global in enumerate(dofs):
        for j_local,j_global in enumerate(dofs):
            K[i_global,j_global] += K_local[i_local,j_local]

def gen_global_F(nodes, forces):
    """Generate the global force vector"""
    F = np.zeros(2*len(nodes))
    for node,(f_x,f_y) in forces.items():
        dof = 2*(node-1)
        F[dof] = f_x
        F[dof+1] = f_y
    return F

def restrain_stiffness(K, F, bounds):
    """Use a given displacement bound to modify matricies"""
    dir = {'x':0, 'y':1}
    for node,this_bound in bounds.items():
        for coord,disp in this_bound.items():
            # Get what dof the bound is
            dof = (node-1)*2 + dir[coord]
            add_disp(K, F, disp, dof)

def add_disp(K, F, disp, n):
    """Move the fixed displacement over to F (since it's constant)"""
    # Get displaced F by reducing by given displacement * stiffness column
    # Must use -= to ensure python evaluates in-place
    #   We don't need to return the array if it's passed by reference
    F -= disp * K[:,n]
    # Set the Force value at that dof to the given displacment
    F[n] = disp
    # Clear stiffness matrix dof row & col
    add_bound(K, n)

def add_bound(K, n):
    """Zero out row and col of dof, then make [n,n] = 1"""
    for i in range(np.size(K,0)):
        K[n,i] = 0
        K[i,n] = 0
    K[n,n] = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set print options if you want to print an array nicely (easier for debug)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True, linewidth=np.inf)
    ex_unm()
    ex_big_boi()

    plt.show()
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Really cool introduction to FEM! I allowed myself to make some corrections and convert some more equations to mathjax, I hope you are ok with that. Some points I noticed that I would suggest improving: If you introduce a new variable, always describe what it is: It doesn't seem clear from the start what \$u\$ is (displacement?) or how \$\beta\$ is defined. Then I'd also try to make the indexing consistent: I'd always use the indices like \$K_i\$ insetad of \$K(i)\$.

Comment: Similarly I'd avoid reusing the same symbol: For example for \$k(1)\$ you reuse the symbol \$k\$ for its entries, so I'd recommend rewriting it as maybe \$\vec k_1\$.

Comment: You talk about the degrees of freedom "dofs", aren't these just the entries of \$u\$?

Comment: And what type of challenge is it anyway? [tag:code-golf] or something else?

Comment: Thanks! Yea, the u vector is the displacement of each node. It is common to have it in the form {node1 x, node1 y, node2 x, node2 y.,,,}. Each element of the vector would be a degree of freedom, and together they would be the degrees of freedom of the entire structure. However, the u vector is not the actual degrees of freedom, it is just the displacements at each degree of freedom. For instance, the force vector would have a force at each degree of freedom. I think it wold be standard code-colf, least bytes wins, however I'm not sure if there's a better challenge it should go into.

Answer (score -2):

## 101 Hello Worlds

I have a project where I'm trying to collect 101 versions of "Hello, World" using obscure and over-engineered approaches in JavaScript/Node.js:

https://github.com/georgemandis/101-hello-worlds

We're up to 38 so far and I've really enjoyed the community contributions.

I recognize the way this is phrased at the moment isn't compatible with the way Code Golf is setup, but I feel like there could be a large overlap with people who might be interested and this community.

Does this seem like something that would be welcome here? Would others have suggestions for how I might re-word this to create a suitable entry for Code Golf?

If it's not suitable or welcome here I respect being downvoted into oblivion and can remove the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for using the Sandbox. The answer is that no, this isn't really suited to the Code Golf site. The closest winning criterion to use would be [tag:popularity-contest], but that was retired a while ago, since it wasn't really objective. If you want inspiration though, you can look at the [tag:hello-world] tag, which has a lot of interesting restrictions on hello world programs. For example, there's no repetition, radiation-hardened, polyglots, palindromes etc.

Comment: Thanks @JoKing. I'll take a look at that tag. I think I'll add a tag to it in my project's README as well to give other people inspiration.

Answer (score -2):

## Hello, World, but *looong*

---

**I couldn't find out that this challenge exists**

**If this challenge exists, let me know**

---

Write a simple *Hello, World!* program.

The winner is the person who has the longest code.

However, ***any*** [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) except itself cannot be the answer.

### Input

You can have input in which way.

### Output

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: [Exact duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824/43319).

Answer (score -2):

## Write an if/else statement from scratch [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

I am new to this community, so please do not hesitate to point out edits and clarifications in this post. Also note that this is just a loose draft for the question. There are several improvements to be made..

#### Task:-

We all use if/else statements in our daily programming life (except the oldies who write Machine code). However, put your feet in a young programmer's shoes. If you wanted to write the `if/else` statement, what would you do?

> So basically you have to re-design or recreate the `if/else` statement in *any* language of your choice.

The `if/else` statement should obviously **not** use `if/else` from any other language. This does not mean that we can use a statement that has some other name in other languages, **no** function/statement that produces `if/else` statement **behavior** can be used.

So this means that functions like `case` etc. which can be used in substitution with `if-else` cannot be used. Neither can you use `while` loops to *simulate* an `if/else`....

#### Ideas:-

On posting this as a question there were a lot of people saying that the challenge was not clear. Can anyone edit or point the mistakes in the lines or think that they can make the question a bit more clear?

> In the simplest words, it is a challenge to write the `if/else` statement without using any of its counterparts (like in other languages it has other names) which can be **used** with a syntax for general cases. For example, it should be able to compare:-

```
arrays
lists
dicts
other data types (heap, stack,tree)
strings
```

Everything a normal `if/else` can do.

Comment: See [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047), in particular [Making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067).

Comment: 1+ have the command `#`, which pops a stack and jump to the nth `#` in the program. Is using `#` allowed?

Comment: Some languages do not have conditional statements, and some have only a `while` loop. Some languages may not have any of your listed data types. You don't know, so it's suggested that you don't write a challenge based on that assumption.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive `#` is a kind of goto, so it's definitely allowed.

Comment: @petStorm Okay then, but I guess we are still waiting for the OP to clarify. Is it allowed to assume there are no `#`s before the snippet?

Comment: I think that `#` can be allowed as long as it works for most of the data types. Atleast commmon types like `string, integers, array` should work with it....

Comment: @S.S.Anne I think that languages that have only a have a `while` loop are automatically disqualified. So any answerer should not use them. What about making **esoteric languages** compulsory? I am sure it will be very tough and feel like a real challenge!

Comment: From the same page, this is *also* discouraged: [Explicitly disallowing or disadvantaging arbitrary (classes of) languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058). Going against the *things to avoid* guidelines will generally mean that your question will be downvoted and/or closed. Try to write a challenge that doesn't do anything that's listed there and it will be more likely that your question will get upvotes and will stay open.

Comment: How can you tell what's an if/else/switch/loop and what's not? This fulfills your requirements, for example: `,[.[-]]+[-[.]]`. I could argue that this contains none of these but you'd never know if it did or not.

Comment: @S.S.Anne So what do you think is the best course of action to take? I don't want to scrap this question because it is really good at its core (but not the best in a practical scenario) Could anyone suggest a very innovative fix so that this question remains a good one?

Comment: You should also look at [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079). I think you should define more clearly what do you want the if-else statement to allow doing. should it allow executing code that can be substituted, given as input based on an input falsy/truthy value?

Comment: I agree that this is far from clear. One additional question I have, is what must we be able to do within our `if/else` replacement. Do we have to be able to run arbitrary sequences of lines of code? Or is just producing a value enough? Note that some languages make a distinction between statements and expressions, and may have `if/else` constructs for one or both situations.

Comment: @neelg As far as I know most Esolangs does not have string and array (as an object). For example, there is only one type in 1+, that is, unsigned integer.

Answer (score -2):

## Produce the next Italy number [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

This is the third post for the [second RGS's Golfing Showdown](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18874/75323).

Italy is a Southern European country that was greatly devastated by the impact of the coronavirus crisis in its fairly aged population. As of the 27th of April, Italy was roughly 600 cases short of hitting 200.000 total confirmed cases.

## Task

Your task is to produce the total number of confirmed cases on day `n+1` given the total number of confirmed cases on day `n`, with `n` going from the 21st of February 2020 to the 10th of April 2020, as per [Wikipedia's data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Italy), obtained at 19:38 27/04/2020 UTC.

For your convenience, these are the 20 numbers involved; the first 19 are inputs and the last 19 are outputs.

```
[20, 79, 150, 229, 322, 445, 650, 888, 1128, 1694, 2036, 2502, 3089, 3858, 4636, 5883, 7375, 9172, 10149, 12462]
```

## I/O

I/O should be integers or reasonable representations of those, with the restriction that your code must accept as input its own output.

## Test cases:

```
20 -> 79
79 -> 150
150 -> 229
229 -> 322
322 -> 445
445 -> 650
650 -> 888
888 -> 1128
1128 -> 1694
1694 -> 2036
2036 -> 2502
2502 -> 3089
3089 -> 3858
3858 -> 4636
4636 -> 5883
5883 -> 7375
7375 -> 9172
9172 -> 10149
10149 -> 12462
```

[Python reference implementation](https://tio.run/##NVDLasMwELz7K4bk0ASU2JafMbTQSyHfEEKQbbkWTSQhyQ1uyLe7ErSXfc3M7rB6dqOS2bKsIRy7znDKJ3TMckswGHWDGzloah3UgA/emomZGZPGJJ24glZuDMi7NuJKwCw0Nxid07aJYy73d/ElNO8F2yvzGYcupglNLp0ySrJvYSZ70Uz2/Ca6i5CXY7ARrXGEvXNmfO5FL18cOqXnYMZytDNGL0GzjeR0a7mxeMWJJgTVgSAtfEGprzJKCfK8ICjDrK5rj6Y0xPKQe1KSlT4WiadlSR0UdeHRvAzzoq4zvzGrvP6QVp6TJmkeDtC8pOcoigZlwAhaCIkfoTd/Zk7NLj0T/Hdpc942EeA/JN1mWD3YE7s3PNrnarssvw)

Comment: Can we use `ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]` for Mathematica? (it involves fetching the data from a server, but 1) it's still built-in 2) so do  many `SomethingData` functions for the first time).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate if that is not against some loophole, sure. Just make sure the numbers coincide with the numbers I posted

Comment: How is this *not* a hard-code the data challenge? Is there any possible relation? Because otherwise, it seems really boring.

Comment: @S.S.Anne thank you for your feedback; I changed the task and reduced the total amount of days we are dealing with. Please let me know if this looks more sensible.

Comment: It's better, but I still don't see how this couldn't be solved without just a big array.

Comment: @S.S.Anne someone will think of something! Hopefully :)

Comment: You can't just hope that someone will find some interesting way to solve your challenge to make a boring challenge interesting. The shortest way I see to solve this right now is to hard-code the data, which is probably what everybody will do.

Comment: Just graph your data, see how much it deviates from only a simple parabola?

Comment: Maybe you could allow some small error bound on the output (say 10%)? Then the challenge would become about finding a model that approximates the data well, rather than hardcoding values

Answer (score -2):

## Make an Anti-compressor (WIP)

Create an algorithm that reversibly and losslessly makes files bigger. You must create the anti-compressor. The de-anti-compressor can be your own creation or something that already exists. The two programs do not need to be written in the same language.

#### Objective Validity Criteria

- Inputs into the anti-compressor can be binary files using any or all byte values.
- All inputs into your anti-compressor must produce outputs that are at least one byte longer.
- The anti-compressor is losslessly reversible by either an existing program or your own.
- The de-anti-compressor must work on (at least) all possible outputs of the anti-compressor.
- Both the anti-compressor and de-anti-compressor can be executed on an actual computer. Keep execution time within reason (e.g. no \$O(n!)\$ programs, please)

---

This will be a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) unless I get a good suggestion for an objective scoring system.

My only idea so far is that the score could be based on the decompression ratio,  cancelled out by how well gzip compresses the output. Unfortunately, this could be abused easily by inserting arbitrarily large amounts of random padding between significant bits of information, leading to an unbounded score that can always be beaten with trivial modification.

Comment: Besides the usual issues with pop-cons, I'd really have no idea how to vote because the task is so broad and I don't know what's meant to be interesting in an answer.

Comment: @xnor that's fair. I'm not entirely sure if this challenge is a good idea in the first place, but I got an upvote earlier, so I thought it might be worth it to refine it and see where it goes. I could see the subjective criteria being along the lines of the funniest or most clever way of anti-compressing a file. Injecting filler data, random or not, is not very clever, but having it output an overly verbose java program that outputs the original file when executed is both humorous and clever- but perhaps not as much as other ideas I haven't even thought of.

Comment: @Λ̸̸  The issue with that scoring system is that you can always make a file more bloated. Someone doubles every byte? I can just triple every byte. That kind of oneupmanship is not interesting. I can try to put limits on exactly what kind of bloating is allowed so that there is some sort of soft upper bound, but then the challenge becomes one of abusing the rules and finding clever interpretations and loopholes- also not very interesting.

Comment: I have an idea: make the answerer choose an existing compression algorithm, and then create an anti-compression program given an input string.The anti-compressed string, when compressed with the chosen algorithm, must produce the exact same output as the input. That way, the anti-compressing method of randomly inserting characters in the input string can be avoided, since there isn't a way to un-double speak a given input character, and for a string with randomly inserted characters, the compressor will not know which characters to leave out during the compression.

Comment: Given that, the scoring criterion can now be simply [tag:code-golf], since there isn't a way to create boring answers, and the only possible way to score answers left is just [tag:code-golf].

Comment: @Λ̸̸ At that point, it would make more sense to make a jillion different [tag:code-golf] challenges since this essentially defines an *entire class* of golfing challenges.

Answer (score -2):

## Print all sequenced variants of the SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) genome in FASTA format

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/sars-cov-2-seqs/

The FASTA format has the name of the sequence data following a `>`, a newline, 60 characters of As, Ts, Cs, and Gs, a newline, 60 characters of As, Ts, Cs, and Gs, and so on.

You need only print the name of the, not the location it came from. For example:

```
>XX-NNNNNN.N
GENOMIC DATA GOES HERE
>XX-NNNNNN.N
MORE GENOMIC DATA GOES HERE
```

Comment: I can't imagine what good does requiring newlines every 60 characters do to the challenge. That site also has very many files linked, and you have not specified which ones we need to use, nor you provided us with the expected output (a plain link to a random website where we have to scrape and parse several thousands of files you haven't told us about is not enough). Since there are thousands of them, I strongly suspect suspect that `zpaq` will win this time.

Answer (score -2):

## Wuhan Xi Estimates

**Challenge**
Create a program that takes two base-ten integer number inputs (*w*,*x*). The program should output the closest integer number that is *x* order of magnitude smaller than *w*,  rounded downwards. The output should be zero if the result is less than 1.


**Test cases**

```
f(10,1) = 1
f(10,2) = 0
f(1000000, 3) = 1000
f(888, 2) = 8
f(99999, 4) = 9
f(7777777, 8) = 0
f(123455, 5) = 1
f(123455, 4) = 12345
f(123455, 0) = 123455
```

**Example Code**
Here's an ungolfed example in **[Lua](https://www.lua.org/)**:

```lua
b=io.read()
a,b=b:match("([^,]+),([^,]+)")

if (b+0 > #a) then 
    print(0)
else 
    d = (a+0)/(10^b)
    print (math.floor(d))
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcfBCoJAEADQc/MVg15mcBItvQT2I1EwkxMu6Ba6fv92iU6PN@@asw3hXa@uIzGo2GCXRdNzooJuD7lXLD8LBggvJKsavGKpjGnyiHD4rCEmahh83vx/q7fdSKWVUo/GjOBxhJzb07nre@m@)

**General rules**

- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes in its respective language wins.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN (with the specification above)/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code ([TIO](https://tio.run/#)).

Comment: Can we take input as string where the two numbers are separated by `"E-"` ?

Comment: @Adám, Is "E-" executable code? If so, I guess that's fine, but it has to be part of the byte count. If it is just a glorified separator, or a switch of some kind, then yes and doesn't have to be included in the byte count.

Comment: My idea what that one could do something like `floor(input)` where input is e.g. `888E-2` thus trivialising the challenge.

Comment: @Adám, That would be fine, and the challenge will have many 'trivial' answers in several languages. I'd be surprised if there isn't atleast a few 2/3 byte solutions.

Comment: Maybe mention in the challenge text that this amounts to computing \$⌊w×10^{-x}⌋\$?

Comment: @Adám, There are other ways to look at it. My Turing Machine Code solution certainly won't be computing any powers.

Comment: Is that integers or positive integers? ;)

Comment: The wording 'closest integer number that is \$x\$ order of magnitude smaller than \$w\$' is ambiguous. I initially interpreted it to mean, e.g., f(1000000, 3) = 9999 (closest integer to 1000000 that is 3 orders of magnitude smaller). As Adám said above, it seems that you're just asking for \$\lfloor w\times 10^{-x}\rfloor\$.

Answer (score -2):

## Meta-golfing Numbers

The Esolangs Wiki has a page [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants) cataloging the shortest known programs in Brainf*** to generate a given number. A similar catalog could exist for any language: it would simply be a list of the shortest known programs in that language outputting a given constant. By extension, we can assume that for any given language, a catalog like this could be generated programmatically, by creating a program that given a constant outputs another program outputting that constant.

### The Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program in any language \$A\$, such that when that program is given an input \$N\$, it outputs a program in language \$B\$ that will ouput \$N\$.

- Languages \$A\$ and \$B\$ need not be different; you can output a program in the same language as your source code.
- All outputted programs *must* be in the same language \$B\$.
- \$N\$ is guaranteed to be a positive integer. It may be \$0\$.

## I/O

- Input and output can be done with any of the [default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- \$N\$ should be inputted as an integer, the string representation of an integer, or an array of digits. Programs should be outputted as a string or a list of characters.

### Restrictions

- Your program must handle values of \$N\$ at least up to \$255\$.
- Trailing whitespace and newlines are allowed, as long as they do not make any program invalid; ie., I can have trailing newlines and whitespace as long as the implementation of \$B\$ allows them in programs.

### Scoring

This question is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most votes wins!

Comment: A critique of the scoring system (and possibly the challenge as a whole): In some languages, the empty program outputs its input, and in some languages, a numeric literal outputs itself. So the optimal submission will be program A, 0 bytes, for a score of 0. But even if the scoring system is changed to prevent the multiplying-by-zero exploit, I don't see how any other approach will be better than the empty-identity-program approach. So as it stands, this challenge will gather multiple trivial answers--and probably some interesting ones, but with worse scores.

Comment: I don't think lowest score wins is a good idea for a contest where you have the flexibility to choose how difficult the task it. Might be better as a popularity contest, or maybe it would be better with a list of difficult languages to print constants in.

Comment: @Razetime yeah, I actually hadn't realized the multiplying by zero exploit, so this seems like the best course of action - I've updated the answer.

Comment: Righ now, this is not metagolf, this is just... meta?

Comment: I guess so, yeah... But metagolf is a bit catchier, isn't it?

Comment: Program: any implementation of cat in any language A. Language B: cat.

Answer (score -2):

## Feedback Wanted

- Is this too vague? should I change it to something like "create a quine with the fewest unique bytes", or perhaps adapt another existing challenge that might otherwise use lots of repeated bytes?
- Maybe the idea is just too boring on its own and I should create a new proper challenge based around it?
- Should I change the scoring system (**votes - unique_bytes**) - should it be divided instead, or use a more complex formula?

## Introduction

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but not as you know it. Instead of every byte,
This is sort-of also a [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) question.

## Challenge

Write an **interesting** program that uses the fewest **unique** bytes. This is not really about what the program does, but what you can do with a limited **set** of characters.

#### Rules

- Your program must run on [Try It Online](https://tio.run)
- Programming languages with only a few permissible bytes anyway like Brainfuck's `+-.,[]<>`, are allowed, but officially considered **boring**

Apart from this, you can write anything.

#### Scoring

- Hybrid of [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and "fewest-unique-bytes". Score is calculated as **votes - unique_bytes**
- Unique bytes is based on bytes, not characters or whatever. You can calculate unique bytes using this Python snippet: `len(set(b"your code here"))`

Comment: It's definitely too vague. "Interesting" could mean anything, and you'd have to argue with several people over whether their ignore-input-and-print-0 program counts as interesting before the challenge is closed as too broad or unclear. [popularity-contest] is also a dangerous tag, in that it's very hard to do well and has fallen out of favor long ago. This extends to all scoring systems that involve votes.

Comment: I think this idea has been largely covered by [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110648/20260). Many languages require surprisingly few characters to run arbitrary code, so I expect there's not much interesting room for specific programs that use fewer characters than needed for that.

Comment: As far as I remember, there exists a Lenguage quine (that uses only 1 unique byte). I think combining popularity-contest with something else is even worse than simply using popularity-contest.

Comment: For future reference, start your sandbox entries with the title of your challenge rather than a generic "feedback wanted". It's the prevailing convention and doing something different is a little confusing to scroll past.

Answer (score -2):

## Solving `P=NP`!

Today, we are going to solve `P=NP`, kinda...

### Input

A guaranteed prime positive integer, `P`.

### Output

The *smallest* composite number (NonPrime,`NP`) which sum of digits equals `P`.

### Examples

```
Input (P)    Output (NP)      Why? (for reference)
  2              20          2+0=2 and 11 is prime
  3              12                 1+2=3
  5              14                 1+4=5
  7              16                 1+6=7
  11             38          3+8=11 and 29 is prime
  13             49                 4+9=13
  17             98          9+8=17 and 89 is prime
```

Check [OEIS A073868](https://oeis.org/A073868) for more results.

### Challenge

Write a function or program that, given a positive prime number `P` as input, calculates `NP`, the smallest composite number which sum of digits equals `P`.

- Range of input: any integer prime number greater than 1, up to the limit of the chosen language.
- Range of output: also according to the limits of the chosen language.
- Means of input/output: free to choose.

### Winning condition

This is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. The shortest code wins!

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

### Meta

I have searched if this was already posted, but with no success.

Comment: To me, this isn't all that interesting of a challenge because it's a mash-up of "find a number whose digit sum is X" and "check if a number is prime." If a language has a built-in for primality, it's done.  If not, it's still been done over and over again.  The fact that the input is prime doesn't really add anything here for me.  And skipping over primes as possible answers doesn't either.  Why not do "find the smallest number whose digits add to X?" or "Find the Yth number whose digits add to X" where both x and y are inputs?

Comment: The challenge itself looks to be well specified but I dislike the title. I'm all for using clever/controversial titles to attract attention, but not at the expense of accurately conveying what the challenge is about.

Answer (score -2):

## English Grammar Checker

[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)[natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)[grammars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars)

Being tired of checking English grammar, I decided to write an English grammar regular expression.

### Notations

1. All capital letters denote an expression.
2. Quoted strings (like `"a"`) and lower-case letters denotes literals.
3. `AB` means concatenating expressions / literals `A` and `B` together.
4. `(...)` groups the expression inside the parentheses, as a whole expression.
5. `A*` means repeating the expression `A` zero or more times.
6. `A?` means the expression `A` is optional here.
7. `A|B` means either `A` or `B` can be placed here.
8. `A=B` means all expression `A` should be replaced by `B`.

### Grammatical Rules

#### Parts of Speech

For simplicity, all parts of speech are substituted using symbols.

| Symbol | Part of Speech |
| --- | --- |
| a | article |
| b | verb |
| j | adjective |
| m | numeral |
| n | noun |
| r | pronoun |
| v | adverb |

#### Rules

There's a whole bunch of rules in English grammar. For simplicity,  I only chose a tip of the iceberg.
Your RegEx should *only* match all valid `S`'s.

1. `S=N+V`
2. `N=((a|m)?j*n(pN)?)|r`
3. `V=b((pN)*|N)?v?`

### Examples

| These should be matched | Real-life example |
| --- | --- |
| `anb` | The man runs |
| `rbpajjnv` | He dives into the deep blue sea quickly |
| `anpanbpr` | The wave on the sea came towards me |
| `mnpambv` | Two friends of the man walks slowly |
| `anpmjjnbajjnv` | The robot of two tall thin girls greets the young handsome man repeatedly |

| These shouldn't be matched | Real-life "wrong" sentences example |
| --- | --- |
| `nn` | Man child |
| `nabr` | Student a told me |
| `arbv` | The you laughed happily |
| `anbvv` | The woman sang slowly beautifully |
| `rbvj` | He is very funny |

*Notice that* the last example *is* a valid English sentence, but it doesn't match our simplified rules. You shouldn't match them.

### Tips

You can assume that there's no whitespaces and line feeds in the input.

You can assume that you only need to match 1 input per time.

You can use any RegEx dialects **no newer than this challenge**.

### Scoring

Your score is the bytes in your RegEx. Flags are not counted.

The least score wins!

Comment: Are you sure that this grammar is really decidable with a regex?

Comment: YES @user202729 and I've already made one; but not decided to make it public yet.

Comment: It's better if you explain what format the rules are specified in. (while I can understand it, it isn't obvious) The standard is Backus-Naur form I guess?

Comment: Any dialect restriction?

Comment: I wrote the format for rules in Notation section; is it unclear?

Comment: Originally I overlook that `=` can be recursive and I can't find capital N in the table.

Comment: Err, yes, but I don't have good ideas about how to explain `=`'s. It's just kind of, substitution? But it can be recursive? Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can show an example of a simple (recursive) pattern matching a simple string.

Comment: Not sure if you're asking an example regex matching a recursive rule. For `A=(yA)|x` using the same notation, regex: `y*x`.

Comment: Does "without flags" mean ", flags are not counted"? That sentence can be interpreted as "regex flags are not allowed" too.

Comment: English grammar is not regular and cannot be matched with a regular expression. At best, you can tease out some subset that is context-free, but realistically, this is not a good challenge as it is written. Natural languages tend to be riddled with all sorts of crazy complexity that makes them highly context-sensitive and possibly undecidable.

Comment: @Beefster As I wrote in the challenge you should only match the simplified "rules", as in section Rules. There're only 3 rules. As I commented before I already wrote a regex that can match these rules, so the challenge is absolutely solvable.

Comment: @Beefster And op did do that. (op claim that the chosen subset is context-free, but I didn't verify it)

Comment: @user202729 if you want to verify, `<S> ::= <N><V>`, `<J> ::= "j"<J> | ""`, `<N> ::= "r" | "a"<J>"np"N | "a"<J>"n" | "m"<J>"np"N | "m"<J>"n" | <J>"np"N | <J>"n"`, `<P> ::= "p"N<P> | ""`, `<V> ::= "b" | "bv" | "b"<N> | "b"<N>"v" | "b"<P> | "b"<P>"v"`. Really verbose.

Comment: Even with this limited subset, reducing it to a regex really only has one optimal approach and isn't particularly interesting in lending itself to many different approaches.

Comment: Even so, not all languages have reggexp support. I would get rid of the regex requirement entirely.

Comment: @Ausername You might have misunderstood the problem: the task is __to write a RegEx__, not a program.

Comment: I understand the question, but I think you're on the wrong website. Code-golf is not finding the single unique solution to a puzzle - see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10064#10064)

Answer (score -2):

Given a positive even integer \$n\$, generate a random Brainfuck snippet of length \$n\$, containing only `+-<>`, that do no modify to the tape or tapehead.

To avoid random generation and try again or
[fallback into a trivial nop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65925/) for invalid nops, your solution should run in polynomial time, and the ratio of possibility returning any two nops should be below polynomial.

Answer (score -2):

Solve any [NPC problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). Shortest code win.

## Sandbox Notes

- Will every submission tend to single NPC problem?
- How many builtins are known to solve this in Mathematica?
- Do 0-byte solution exist?

Comment: I think this is too broad to be a good challenge

Comment: Dyalog Extended can solve it in two bytes: `⌂X` (Knuth's X algorithm which solves the [Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem).

Comment: @Bubbler Lots of language will have builtin for this question I guess

Answer (score -2):

Compress La Campanella.

Notice that music theory may give you more rules than general compress give, but I don't know music theory that much, so I won't post this

Answer (score -2):

## Self-Obfuscator Program

According to Wikipedia,

> obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating source or machine code
> that is difficult for humans to understand.

In this challenge, you need to create a program that'll be able to obfuscate itself and produce a program with the same functionality, using the shortest amount of bytes required.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are prohibited.
- The output must always be consistent for each input. If you take the original code (*iteration 0*) and run it through itself 10 times to get a very long obfuscated code (*iteration 10*), running the initial code through it should give a code identical to *iteration 1* code.
- The output must be at least twice as long from the input for each iteration.

#### Obfuscated, not verbose

- The obfuscation process must make the code longer, but it mustn't add any comments, no-op or no-effect statements, or any statements or expressions that **don't directly affect the output code**.
- The output should have minimal resemblance to the input. No sequence of 5 bytes should repeat in the output.
- The code must be able to obfuscate itself, obfuscations of itself from further ahead iterations and code from earlier iterations. It's not required to be able to obfuscate anything else.

Comment: Bonus in code golf is highly discouraged. And "the output should have minimal resemblance to the input" should be more rigorously defined.

Comment: The idea is fine, but you need more detailed and cleaner define about obsfucate and the meaning of `statement that don't directly affect the output code`

Answer (score -2):

## The number of alphabets in 3 seconds

[fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

In 3 seconds, output as many alphabets as possible. The output may be separated by consistent character.

An alphabet here is this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

## Meta

- Is this clear?
- I'm not really sure about the tagging.

Comment: This should be closed, because machine code can do this with a lot of "A" prints without loops and win. this is off-topic

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic as it have a clear "objective winning criteria". But I am afraid that this question may be marked as a duplicate to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215216/high-throughput-fizz-buzz

Answer (score -2):

## TDG - Test Driven Golf

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Our company requires unit testing before code can be deployed to production. Unfortunately, my code is written in esoteric programming languages, none of which have test runners.

Please help me get to production!

### Challenge

Write a test runner for a programming language (here after called Language X) that takes Language X source code and Language X test cases then outputs the results of running the test cases.

NOTE: The language used to write the test runner does not necessarily have to be Language X.

### Specification

#### Input

The runner should take in:

- Code written in Language X
- Test cases written in Language X

#### Output

The runner should produce:

- At least a list of test cases. For each test case, include:

  - The test case name
  - A [Truthy value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) if the code executes without errors and no assertions failed
  - A [Falsey value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) if the code errors or an assertion failed

#### Test Runner

- The test runner can be written in any language. The only constraint is that the source and test code language be the same
- Each test runner must at least provide a helper/utility/function to assert that a value is [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)

  - `Assert.True(false)` => Fails test
  - `assertTrue(1 == 3)` => Fails test
  - `is_truthy 1` => Doesn't fail
  - `[[ "a" = "a" ]]` => Doesn't fail

#### Test Cases

- Each test case must have a name/be name-able

  - `it("does stuff", _ => ...)` => it does stuff
  - `it_does_stuff = _ => ...` => it_does_stuff
  - `func ItDoesStuff() {...}` => ItDoesStuff
- A code block of language X code

#### Submissions

For consistency, here are some recommendations:

- Title should be: `# Language X runner written in Language Y`

  - Where Language X is the source and test code language
  - And Language Y is the language the runner is written in
- Runner code in a `## Runner` section
- Example input source code in a `## Example Source` section
- Example input test code in a `## Example Tests` section
- Example output in a `## Example Output` section

### Sandbox Questions

- Is this challenge too board?
- Is this challenge too big?
- I've created some basic test runners in a single file before and with some elbow grease, I think you could say small (submit-able on CGCC) and add a few nice things
- Does [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) fit here?
- Is there room for creativity?

  - The testing syntax and features for the test cases are left up to the implementation

    - How golf-able the test syntax is
    - How the code and test cases interact
    - What asserts/helpers are provided
    - Syntax for skipping test cases
    - Syntax for beforeEach/afterEach
    - Harder features like parameterized tests and fixtures are possible
  - Similarly, the features for the test runner are left pretty open
    ended

    - [TAP](https://testanything.org/producers.html) output
    - [JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4926073/4769802) output
    - Test isolation and parallelization
    - Harder features like specific failure messages and code coverage aren't *impossible*

Comment: "Input: Source code written in language X, Test cases written in language X" I don't understand. Are we providing the input to our own programs? Or are we meant to detect the language?

Comment: This doesn't make sense as a pop-con, there's very little room for creativity

Comment: @thejonymyster, I've added some clarity (hopefully). The test runner should be for testing a specific language (no detecting) and it would take in some code (not it's own source) and some tests in that language.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, there is a fair spectrum of test runners and testing syntaxes out there. So I was thinking there was some room for creativity (especially since I don't think any of them are made for golfing). I've added some comments to that end. I couldn't think of a better tag

Answer (score -2):

## Alternate brackets

Given a matched string containing only `()[]{}`, apply the following:

- If `[]` is next to `()` or `{}`, replace the `()` or `{}` with `[]`.
- If a `()` follows `[]` or `{}`, remove the `()`.

## Test cases

```
()[]{} => [][][]
{}(){} => (){}
```

Comment: This doesn't have a scoring criterion, and is also in need of some more explaining - if we have `[]()`, which rule should apply?- The first is second? Your second test case also makes no sense as it doesn't follow either of the rules...

Answer (score -2):

### Task

Make a program that finds the first IP address that responds to pings after a certain IP address.

### Requirements

Your program should take an IP address as a string in the form `xx.xx.xx.xx`. It should find the first IP greater than the input (incrementing least significant byte first) that responds to pings, and output it in the form `xx.xx.xx.xx`.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: This... feels morally unsafe. Although responding to a ping is generally not-malicious, IP scrapping doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score -2):

Write a program on any language that accepts some input and give some different output. The challenge is that the text of the program must form a square: all rows must be the same length and the number of rows must equal the number of columns (ie length of rows). Adding extra spaces, dead code, or comments to pad lines is not allowed.

This is Code Golf so the one with the shortest functioning program (ie smallest square) wins!

Comment: First I would recommend adding title using `#` markdown. Then adding tags  [tag:code-golf] and [tag:source-layout] using `[tag:name]` markdown. Also you should probably specify output a bit better. Does it need to be different for every input or can it be always same? Also in some [programming languages](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) spaces are actually instructions.

Comment: I believe a square code challenge has been done.

Also, this is ultimately about the features of the language rather than any particular skill of the programmer.  The minimum score is the length of whatever the language's equivalent of "print" is.

Answer (score -2):

## Self-Debugger.

Suddenly, someone comes and deletes a character from the program. From analyzing the output and error messages (if any), you quickly know which character was deleted.

Your job is to create a function that does this. For every character deletion, you will get one point if feeding the output and error message(s) to the undamaged function does **not** give the correct deleted character. You attempt to **minimize the score of your program**. Your program must have a function, i.e. if must not be empty.

Default loopholes forbidden, as always.

Example program:

```python
lambda a,aa:'a'
```

Score: the program is not correct when we take away a character that is not `a`. Thus, the score is `9`. (We intend to minimize this score.)

[coding-challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-challenges)

Comment: Meta: we need tags!!!

Comment: Why even take the stdout as input? What could you possibly do with this info that would improve your score?

Comment: stdout could be useful

Comment: The entire second paragraph makes no sense to me

Comment: Ouch, let me explain it a bit more

Comment: Done, @mousetail

Comment: Ok I see what you are going for, fix the name and remove the first sentence though since they have nothing to do with the challenge

Comment: Now?sdkvwoefjowejfojweojfowepjfpowejpofwe

Comment: I'd name it what the challenge actually is "from the output and error determine what character was removed from your code"

Comment: But I think it is too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138805/discussion-between-number-basher-and-mousetail).

Comment: [Dupe of this?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154286/radiation-detector)

Comment: No. We give the unradiated program the output and error of the radiated program.

Comment: Ohh so it's more of a narcisist type thing, that makes sense. Interesting

Answer (score -2):

## Robotics competition

You're entering a robotics competition! There are 3 types of parts for you to choose for your robot: wheels, legs and sensors. A robot:

- can have up to 8 parts in total
- can only have 4 legs
- must have at least 2 parts
- must have at least one leg or one wheel

You can't decide what robot to build, so you'll just make all of the possible ones. How many robots will you build?

### The challenge

Write a program which calculates the number of possible robots (the answer is 134). Shortest program wins.

The output of your program **can** be its return code. The program needn't take any input (undefined behaviour if input is provided).

Bonus swag points for a point-free solution in APL

### Example

A non-competitive python example:

```python
from itertools import chain, combinations_with_replacement

options = list(filter(
    lambda option: \
        len(option) >= 2 and \
        option.count('leg') <= 4 and \
        (option.count('leg') + option.count('wheel') > 0),
    chain(*(combinations_with_replacement(('leg', 'wheel', 'sensor'), j) for j in range(9)))
))

for option in options:
    print(option)
print("Number of valid options: {}".format(len(options)))
```

## META

- Is the question original enough, or has there been any challenges like this
- Is the python example a useful thing to include?

Comment: Seems like `print(134)` would be a valid answer. Challenges that require no input need to be careful to be more difficult than just printing the answer. Limiting answers to just one specific strategy is also discouraged since it reduced the creative freedom and subjective rules are annoying when trying to get the best possible answer.

Comment: @mousetail thanks for the input! :)) i'll have a think on how to modify the challenge and see if i can make it work. cheers.

Answer (score -2):

## ABACABA pattern without recursion

[ABACABA pattern on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABACABA_pattern)

Taking a number `n` as input, generate the ABACABA pattern with `n` symbols as stated in the above page, without using any form of recursion in your code. You can use any output method; characters, a list of numbers, an image, whatever is possible.

If taking input is not possible in your programming language, output the pattern forever. E.g.: `ABACABADABACABAE...`

Test cases:

````
input => output

1 => A / 1
2 => ABA / 1, 2, 1
3 => ABACABA / 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1
4 => ABACABADABACABA / 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1
5 => ABACABADABACABAEABACABADABACABA / 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1
```
````

Comment: Please add some information on what exactly the ABACABA pattern _is_.

Comment: Also, "no recursion" is an unobservable requirement.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68978/generate-the-abacaba-sequence)

Answer (score -2):

## Detect if a variable is declared

Create an expression which detects if a variable (named whatever you wish) has been declared yet. For languages that set undeclared variables to a type that can not be differentiated from a declared variable set to that type (e.g. `nil` in Lua), just detecting that type is enough. If the variable exists, the expression should return a truthy value, and if it doesn't it should return a falsy value. It should not output anything.

For example, the following expression in D detects if a variable named `x` has been declared in the current scope or not:

```
__traits(compiles, x)
```

*PS:* this challenge definitely wouldn't work for stack-based or assembly languages, and I'm also not sure if marking this as `code-golf` or `popularity-contest` would be better.

Comment: [tag:code-golf] is nearly always better. [tag:popularity-contest]s are *really* hard to write properly. Also, note that some stack based languages *do* have variables

Comment: ```For languages that set undeclared variables to a type that can not be differentiated from a declared variable set to that type (e.g. nil in Lua), just detecting that type is enough.
```

What does this mean? Are you saying a variable with a value of nil should return false, and a variable with a value of anything else should return true? If so, there are probably better ways to word it.

Answer (score -2):

## PHPFuck Golf - Hello World

Like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17950)

> PHPFuck is an esoteric language in which any PHP statement can
> be accurately reproduced into another valid PHP program that
> uses only the 5 characters `(^.9)`.
>
> The PHPFuck converter, when given an input of `echo "Hello World!"`,
> produces a block of code that is 74,450 characters long. Because the
> program used a lot of automatic conversions to create that block, I
> believe that the code can be made a lot shorter using manual
> optimizations.
>
> Your task is to build a PHP program that performs the task
> `echo "Hello World!"`, using only the characters `(^.9)`. The shortest
> code to do so wins.

Answer (score -2):

## Polishing off a Sudoku

Given a set of 8 numbers as input, output the missing one.

### Examples

`12346789` -> `5`

`94351726` -> `8`

Comment: I am fairly certain this is a dupe of a more general question. [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/114060/67312) was the first I could find, though I feel like there was one with an arbitrary range too.

Answer (score -2):

## Print the input times infinity

Make a program/function that prints the input of the function infinite times, separated be a line break. Do note that the output must be to stdout.
tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Might get marked as duplicate of [Implement a truth-machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000) or [Simple cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/simple-cat-program?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C0.0000)

Comment: Why? It endlessly returns the input _with a newline_ regardless of what it is

Comment: It’s not the same challenge, but I think it’s likely to be marked as a dupe of one of those since most answers to that can be easily ported to your challenge (this practice of handling duplicates is fairly common on this site)

Comment: @noodleman Really? My answer (in (,))  was very different.

Comment: [Exact dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124662/create-a-parrot-program) [restricted-source version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/yes-is-91-lines-long) [fastest-code version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199528/fastest-yes-in-the-west)

Answer (score -2):

## That is disproportionate!

You want to overwhelm your nasty boss with an error message so large that they quit their job. But your boss will fire you instead if it's too long.

---

### Challenge

In this challenge, you have to write code that is **more than 0 bytes long** that produces the longest error message possible.

### Scoring

Answers will be scored using this formula:
$$\frac{\text{Error message length in bytes}}{\text{Programme length in bytes}}$$

### Other

All answers must **include the answer score, source code and error message.**

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[error-message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-message)

---

## Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Any other appropriate tags?
- Anything else?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217844/91213 which was also closed as duplicate of the generic non-error verison

Answer (score -2):

## KCMCK

Print this ASCII art:

```
  +--------------  +-+                   +-+   +--------------  |
 ++                | |                   | |  ++                |
 |                 |  \                  / |  |                 |
 |                 |   \                /  |  |                 |
 |                 |    \              /   |  |                 |
 |                 |     \            /    |  |                 |
 |                 |      \          /     |  |                 |
 |                 |       \        /      |  |                 |
 |                 |        \      /       |  |                 |
 |                 |         \    /        |  |                 |
 ++                |          \  /         |  ++                |
  +--------------  |           \/          |   +--------------  |
________________________________________________________________|
________________________________________________________________|
```

Shortest code in characters wins!

- Any leading whitespace must be the same on every line.
- No restrictions on trailing whitespace.

Answer (score -2):

## Be a cat

I have not found a single challenge that asks for a plain cat programme. The closest I have found requires you to print `cat goes meow` when the input is `cat`.

---

In this challenge, you must read everything from `STDIN`, or an acceptable alternative, and print the exact text to `STDOUT`, or an acceptable alternative, with only the leading and trailing whitespace in the input.

---

### Meta

- Have I been so silly that I missed a duplicate?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62230/114446

Answer (score -2):

## Type annotation

Given a function definition and a list of types, both valid in your language, output the function annotated with those types. Shortest code wins, since this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Meta

- Is it a duplicate?
- How should I include languages without type annotation support?
- Does it need to be explained better?
- Anything else?

Answer (score -2):

## Execute... yourself!

[Almost a duplicate, but only requires you to compile a subset, and is closed.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/471/self-compiling-compiler)

---

You work at a compiler factory, making compilers tailored to your customers.

---

### Challenge

In a programming language of your choice, write a program that executes code in the chosen language. Snippets are allowed, but you may not hardcode the input.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

---

### Meta

- To deal with languages like [No](https://esolangs.org/wiki/No.), should I change it to a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), or disallow languages like that completely?
- Is it clear enough?
- Are there any unclosed challenges this duplicates?
- Anything else?

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler)

Comment: duplicate?: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/585/self-interpreting-interpreter

Comment: @bsoelch No. This challenge requires you to interpret all of your language, and allows the use of `eval`.

Comment: Related: [Self-Interpreting Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/585), [Interpreted Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55615)

Comment: Allowing `eval` doesn't actually change much— you're just going to get a bunch of submissions that are just the eval function (or equivalent).

Answer (score -2):

## Spaceman Simulator

The song [A Spaceman Came Travelling](https://genius.com/2172507) presents a fictional story about an alien coming to earth and singing; it is loosely based on the account of the birth of Jesus. The spaceman first says this:

> Then the stranger spoke, he said "Do not fear
> I come from a planet a long way from here
> And I bring a message for mankind to hear,"
> And suddenly the sweetest music filled the air
> And it went
> "La la la la la la la la la la la
> La la la la la la la la
> La la la la la la la la la la la
> Peace and goodwill to all men, and love for the child
> La la la la la la la la la la la
> La la la la la la la
> La la la la la la la la la la la"

The next day, he returns:

> And just before dawn at the paling of the sky 
> The stranger returned and said "Now I must fly 
> *When two thousand years of your time has gone by* 
> This song will begin once again, to a baby's cry."

Write a program that prints this string, followed by two newlines:

```
Do not fear
I come from a planet a long way from here
And I bring a message for mankind to hear

La la la la la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la la la la
Peace and goodwill to all men, and love for the child
La la la la la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la la la la
```

Then, wait until just before dawn at the paling of the sky (approximated by 06:00 system time), and print this, also followed by two newlines:

```
Now I must fly
When two thousand years of your time has gone by
This song will begin once again, to a baby's cry
```

(If the program is run exactly at 06:00, you may either do this immediately or wait 24 hours.)

Finally, wait until two thousand years of our time has gone by, and begin the song once again. (This goes on in an infinite loop; it will print everything three times if you run it for six thousand years.)

Since it's not feasible to wait thousands of years to see if a program works properly, also include an explanation of why the full version works. If you golf the text generation for any of the parts, please also include a copy of the code for each part to generate the text, separate from the main program; this way it can be determined that your [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) code works without waiting for the paling of the sky or the return of the spaceman.

For the 2,000 year delay, wait until the same time (within a second or so accuracy) and date as when the program was started (not after the dawn), 2,000 years later.

You may assume that system time will increase monotonically throughout eternity, and that the time zone will never change.

If there is no way to wait for a duration or until a time in your language, then you may only output the text, as a complete submission would have printed 2,000 years after dawn. This will make the challenge easier in these languages, but will not give them an advantage in competing because submissions only compete within one language.

### Example implementation

Here's an example in ungolfed Python. [It will not work on Windows.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196917/sleep-for-1000-years#comment468554_196932)

```python
import datetime
import time

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if now.hour < 6:
        day_of_next_dawn = datetime.date.today()
    else:
        day_of_next_dawn = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    dawn = datetime.datetime(
        day_of_next_dawn.year,
        day_of_next_dawn.month,
        day_of_next_dawn.day,
        6,
        0,
    )

    in_two_thousand_years = now.replace(year=now.year + 2000)

    print(
        """Do not fear
I come from a planet a long way from here
And I bring a message for mankind to hear

La la la la la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la la la la
Peace and goodwill to all men, and love for the child
La la la la la la la la la la la
La la la la la la la
La la la la la la la la la la la
"""
    )

    time.sleep((dawn - now).total_seconds())

    print(
        """Now I must fly
When two thousand years of your time has gone by
This song will begin once again, to a baby's cry
"""
    )

    time.sleep((in_2000_years - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
```

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Sleep for 1000 years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196917/108687

Comment: @noodleman would it be a non-duplicate if I changed it to "print the song, wait until the next morning in local time, print the 'Now I must fly' text, wait two thousand years, and start the cycle over"?

Comment: That would be further from a duplicate, but I'm not convinced it wouldn't be closed anyway. You may have noticed, but this site tends to close song-based kolmogorov-complexity challenges with high frequency.

Answer (score -2):

## Write an optimal Python program for distributed worknode to find prime.

Prime is defined as a number with no divisor but 1 and itself. Write an optimised for speed program for Pythons distributed worknode to check if an input is a prime.

The usual approach is to try possible divisors to see if they are, an optimisation begins at 2 (since we have to find n/2 anyway for a limit) and does not try multiples of a possible divisor, if a number does not divide by two then no even numbers divide that number, similarly if a number does not divide by three then it does not divide by three, six and nine. No number higher than n/2 need to be tried.

Entries in programming languages other than Python are acceptable for study.

Comment: Is 1 considered prime?

Comment: @AlanBagel 1 is self prime.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Willtech101/status/1740264912742764670?t=4BJEEj3-kqhDDMWZEfyTjg&s=19

Comment: ? (filler filler)

Comment: Not popular? Probably there is already a real world solution I will work on it here https://github.com/Willtech/Prime

Comment: @AlanBagel Actually I was looking even -3 is considered prime and 2.

Answer (score -2):

## Tiniest ELF under x64 Linux to perform ROT13

We already have a ROT13 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input). But all those solutions, while short in *source form*, require/produce huge binaries in order to run. A simple C implementation ends up at around ~14 *KiB*! If that doesn't shock you, see the quoted text below from [this](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/03/a-brief-tour-of-the-pdp-11-the-most-influential-minicomputer-of-all-time/) article (emphasis mine):

> The first version of UNIX was written in PDP-11 assembler; it had 34 system calls, it was written in 4,200 lines of code, and it ran on **12KB** of main memory

### Goal

Create the [tiniest ELF **executable**](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/) you can that runs under x64 Linux (4.14+), takes input from `stdin`, performs [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) on it and writes the result to `stdout`.

### Notes

- You may use whatever language you want (C, C++, Rust, Assembly, Hex, ...), but please provide version numbers and your environment, as well as any extra necessities (compiler/linker flags, linker scripts, custom scripts, commands, etc.) so that we can reproduce the result.
- You may assume input will always be in ASCII.
- It has to be a relatively complete program. You *must* handle errors (mainly, a system call failing). The program must exit with exit code `0` on sucess and `1` on failure.
- I encourage you to try higher-level languages. Answers in assembly will, no doubt, be shorter, but it's interesting to see how others will fare.

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (no loopholes), the smallest binary wins!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [machine-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-code)

Comment: I feel this is still a dupe of the rot13 challenge. a Tiny Elf binary would be valid for the Rot13 challenge.

Comment: @ATaco A C (or any other language) answer that produces a tiny ELF can compete in this challenge but not in the original.

Comment: I get it, but even a C answer is probably just going do directly emit assembly, which doesn't make for a very interesting change of the original challenge.

Answer (score -3):

### Code-challenge: Guess my number

#### The challenge

You have a number from 1 to 10 in mind, and your program should ask questions to find out which number. These questions can be any questions, the program only has to find out the number as fast as possible.

Your program should ask a question, such as "Is the number a prime?", and the user must answer either *y* or *n* (yes or no). Ask questions until you know the number.

#### The scoring

To calculate the score, you need to take the sum of the question count for each number. For example, if you need 1 question to find the number 1, 2 questions to find the number 2, and so on, the score is `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10`, so the score is 55.

**Important note:** the question count for a specific number must *always* be the same. For example, if you need 4 questions to find out the number 10, then you have to ask *always* 4 questions to find out the number 10, otherwise it is impossible to calculate the score.

Comment: boooring. The Huffman tree for a uniform set is any perfectly balanced tree. The question asks us to perform a binary search on the `usr` device. Is the number greater than 5? Is the number greater than 2? Is the number greater than 1? Hey' I think it's 1.

Comment: Maybe if this were a pop-contest and the goal was to make the most original set of questions while still keeping the score at its theoretical minimum.

Comment: This is off-topic and AI is off-topic for this site

Answer (score -3):

## Popularity Contest: Implementation of a Hash Table

Create a class in some OOP language for a hash table that supports getting, setting, and removing values. You can't use the built in hash table/dictionary/map implementation. Highest votes in one week wins.

A key is any valid string. A value is any valid string, number, or boolean.

Example functionality:

```
hash.set("key","value");
hash.get("key"); // returns "value"
hash.set("key", 1234);
hash.get("key"); // returns 1234
hash.set("key2",hash.get("key"));
hash.get("key2"); // returns 1234
hash.delete("key");
hash.get("key"); // returns null/undefined/none/etc. or throws an error
hash.get("key2"); // still returns 1234
```

Definition of a hash table (from Wikipedia):

> In computing, a hash table (also hash map) is a data structure used to implement an associative array, a structure that can map keys to values. A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an array of buckets or slots, from which the correct value can be found.

The hash table cannot be simply an array that is searched in linear time. It must be an actual hash table that uses a hash function to map the keys to the value.

Comment: Popularity contest and shortest don't mix. That aside, the spec is too vague. What is a "value"? What assumptions can be made about hashcodes? If the language makes all types nullable, should `null` be permitted as a key? What should the type be in languages which have co- and contravariance? And for that matter, what qualifies as a "hash table", bearing in mind that people will try to exploit any loophole?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for the feedback! Please see my edits, and let me know what you think. Could you meant about co/contravaraince? I looked at the wikipedia article about it but I'm not really sure how that has anything to do with this question.

Comment: I think it's still vulnerable to the loophole of "I have a hashtable with one bucket" (i.e. it's really a list of (key, value) pairs which I traverse in linear time). The thing about variance is to do with static typing of the elements of the map. E.g. in Java `Map<String, Integer>`'s `get` method has signature `public Integer get(Object)`; in C#, a `Dictionary<string, int>`'s `Get` method has signature `public int Get(string)`. The edited version makes it clear enough that the hashtable isn't expected to be genericised.

Answer (score -3):

**Bovine Ignorance**

I'm curious about code which still works after being mangled by `figlet`, `toilet`, `cowsay` et al, but I'm not sure whether this in any way sane.

What I'm toying with is a challenge in which a participant may submit any program in any language. It should be possible to use this program's source code as input to `cowsay` or whatever, and the result should be another valid program in any language, which still does a similar thing. For instance, the following bf program prints `Hello world!` with no newline:

```
+++++ +++++
[
> +++++ ++
> +++++ +++++
> +++
> +
<<<< -
]
> ++ .
> + .
+++++ ++ .
.
+++ .
> ++ .
<< +++++ +++++ +++++ .
> .
+++ .
----- - .
----- --- .
> + .
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Running `cat ./prog.bf | cowsay -e .. -T $'>.'` yields the following output:

```
 _________________________________________
/ +++++ +++++ [ > +++++ ++ > +++++ +++++  \
| > +++ > + <<<< - ] > ++ . > + . +++++   |
| ++ . . +++ . > ++ . << +++++ +++++      |
| +++++ . > . +++ . ----- - . ----- --- . |
| > + .                                   |
| +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ |
\ ++                                      /
 -----------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (..)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
             >. ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Which is itself a valid bf program which prints `Hello world!!!`, followed by a newline.

The problem with using bf here is that it ignores most of the cow, making this a bit too easy. The problem with using any other language is that it doesn't ignore most of the cow, making this far too difficult. Is there a sensible middle ground I could pick for this? I don't think it's impossible, I'm fairly sure you can exploit cowsay's behavior on one-liners to produce valid `svg`s, but I'm not sure how best to pose this challenge. Any ideas?

Comment: I could not think of any language that falls in the middle ground. Even brainfuck is affected by the `-----------------------------------------..>.----` inserted by cowsay. Most languages have strong parsing rules that would not cope with being post-processed by cowsay. The few exceptions for this will be either completely unaffected or badly affected, making the challenge uninteresting.

Comment: Actually, you can't transform just any brainfuck program to cowsay-brainfuck. Namely those that can output fewer than three characters cannot be transformed at all.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I was intending to allow competitors to choose the parameters of their calls to cowsay. For the uninitiated, -e controls the string used for eyes and defaults to `oo`, and -T controls the string used for the tongue, defaulting to ` U`. This is all yak-shaving, though, and having written this up and read the comments, I suspect that this idea has neither legs, horns nor udders.

Comment: If I could propose a variant that is more feasible, you could do a challenge like "Write a program in your language of choice that draws ASCII art of a cow saying something (does *not* have to be identical or even similar to the cowsay art). The entire drawing must itself be valid source code that does something other than no-op. Post results of both programs." That gives people more leeway to work around the specific restrictions of their compiler.

Comment: Ok, I found a language that falls within the middle ground: whitespace. Anyway, this question has a too narrow scope to develop an interesting challenge.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre That would be a subjective validity criterion, and would probably be closed as too broad.

Answer (score -3):

## 99 Bottles of Errors

While there are already many versions of "print 99 Bottles of Beer," I thought another one wouldn't hurt.

---

The challenge is fairly simple: print the lyrics to *99 bottles of Beer* to `STDERR`. I don't care how you do it, so long as the entire lyrics show up. An entire program is required, so the following Java program would be invalid (even if it did do the correct thing):

```
System.out.println("99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall, take one down and pass it around...");
```

### The scoring:

- This challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code by byte count wins.
- If necessary, assume UTF-8 is the character encoding used.

### The rules

- All the code must be in one file.
- Any language is allowed.
- Reading input, whether it is from `STDIN`, a file, or the web, is not allowed.

Comment: This is trivial in some languages (Java), where it reduces to a simple kolmogorov challenge, and impossible in others (those that have no distinct STDERR)

Answer (score -3):

## Create an Identicon Generator

The challenge is to create an identicon generator.  The identicons must be randomly generated, so we get a new identicon for each key the program receives.  You can input a key using std-in or you can use your language's random number generator for the key.

In order to make your identicon look reasonably nice, it must generate a picture, then rotate that picture around the bottom right corner, the way this mockup shows:

[image]

The output must be to a PNG file.  Shortest code wins.

Comment: Far too broad. As this stands I can create a 1-pixel image whose colour is just the key. I don't think this question will be ready to go until you've found a way to prevent me from making the images differ only in their palette (and to pre-empt, I think that adding a rule "Images may not differ only in their palette" isn't a real fix).

Comment: If you just ask for "random" images, you'll get images that are either hardly random at all (a solitary pixel in a random location), or completely random (noise). To get something "reasonably nice", you'll have to provide *very clear* instructions on how to produce these images. I suggest you try creating a few of these yourself, and find a minimal set of rules that produces results that look OK. Include requirements on dimensions (100x100px?), selection of colours (at least 2, not too similar), and drawing method (e.g., "five triangles with random vertices and a minimum area of 20 px²").

Comment: How important is the PNG file output? This will be a challenge in itself for many languages. Would you accept an uncompressed non-interlaced format like PPM?

Answer (score -3):

## Shortest Program that May or May not Terminate:

Write a program such that whether or not it terminates depends on the answer to an unsolved question in Computer Science or Mathematics. For example, your program might test the Goldbach conjecture for every N and quit if a counterexample is found, or hunt for odd perfect numbers. Please include an explanation of why your program may or may not terminate!

Note: assume infinite memory and stack size, because otherwise they all terminate. Your program must be self contained, take no input, and only use standard libraries.
This is Codegolf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: What about "unsolvable" problems, e.g. halting problem? Can I take another code as input and terminate if that terminates? Because that other program may or may not terminate, and there's no way to tell.

Comment: The intention was that the program isn't allowed to take input. I'll be more specific.

Comment: Does this differ from [this previous question in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/2111#2111)?

Comment: (even if not the comments explaining why that one wouldn't work as a question may help Taylor this one)

Comment: The intent of this doesn't differ significantly from the question you linked, I searched posted questions but forgot to search the sandbox.

Comment: Infinite memory isn't required.

Answer (score -3):

## Every number is interesting

We know that [every number is interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) but how?

You should write a program or function which:

- takes a list of `N` positive integers (>0 and <2^31)
- outputs `N` lines each of them showing how the corresponding input number is interesting
- is not longer than 1024 bytes
- uses no more than 1 second per number
- doesn't use external sources

### Examples

```
172: 444 in base6
5776: 76*76
9801: 9 * 1089 (reverse)
68101: no 11 in base2 (10000101000000101)
491033: 317 * 1549 (product of 2 big primes)
467808816: no digit 5 from base6 to base10
```

### Inputs

You should include the output for the following input in your post:

```
58 92 120 224 358 490 912 1578 7812 222008 1645060 19796411 550453633
```

If you care to run your program on a bigger sample and share the result with us use [this input data](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=969HyE12) (2500 numbers). (You can upload your output to e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).)

This is a popularity-contest so highest voted answer wins.

Tags:  popularity-contest, number

Comment: What sort of criteria are necessary for defining a number as 'interesting'? I see things like square numbers, other bases, etc. But are there any specifics? I'm interested in this challenge (but worried it might be closed as too broad).

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI There wasn't a clear definition. That's part of the reason why I abandoned the challenge.

Comment: Would you mind if I tried taking it up? I would have to post as a new answer, because I can't directly edit.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Not at all.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Where did you post it?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I am also curious

Comment: I don't think he posted it or at least with this account. (he only has asked 1 question and it is not this one).

Answer (score -3):

## Something Else - ASCII Art maker:

A text to ASCII art generator maker, the program must input a string and return ASCII art from it. Something like [patorjk.com/software/taag/](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/). It has to use the Graffiti font. The winning criteria is the whoever gets the most likes.

Comment: Hello! Just a few things to point out: 1) The current spec is very broad. For example, what fonts, how does spacing look, what characters need to be supported... there's a lot more details that need to be included than just "return ASCII art of this text"

Comment: 2) What's the winning criterion? Popularity contest? Code golf?

Answer (score -3):

## Identifying a Sonnet

This challenge is about determining if a given file (read-in from stdin) meets the criteria to be a sonnet. You may use any language for this challenge. If your language supports an API to use an online dictionary you may use that API, if your language doesn't then too bad.

Additionally, it is preferred if your language is one that can be ran directly from the command line and is a language that has a compiler or interpreter available directly from my distro's repos(Fedora), as I would rather just use a bash script to test the various programs, then test each program manually.

## Definition of a Sonnet

- Has 14 Lines (lines are denoted as the standard newline on your operating system).
- Has a definite rhyme scheme, it will have one of the following rhyme schemes

  - `ABBA` `ABBA` `CD` `CD` `CD`
  - `ABBA` `ABBA` `CDE` `CDE`
  - `ABAB` `ABBA` `EFEF` `GG`
- Iambic Pentameter - consists of alternating stressed, unstressed syllables. 
  This doesn't have to be perfect 100% of the time, just at least 50% of the
  time.

In order for your program to declare a given string a sonnet, it must meet all of the above criteria.

### Additional Notes

You do not have to identify the following:

- Thought Structure - too intense for a code golf challenge, and too subjective.
- Topic - computer lacks context to determine this

## Input

Input will be read from stdin. This is the string that you will be declaring *to be or not to be* a sonnet.

## Output

Your program will output either yes or no for the question:

> Does this string meet the given requirements to be a sonnet?

As this is code golf yes or no can be abbreviated to `Y/N`.

## Winner

The solution with fewest number of bytes win that has the highest accuracy ratio for the correct identification of a sonnet. The preference is for higher accuracy rather than brevity of the program.

## Test Data and Resources

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet)
- [Test Data](http://www.webexhibits.org/poetry/explore_famous_sonnet_examples.html) - You have to copy and paste yourself, but it does have examples.
- [Shakespheare?](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/) - All of Shakespheares sonnets are here

### What is not a sonnet

The following are examples that you program should return false on:

- [Beowulf](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/180445)
- Haiku
- Input that doesn't have **exactly** 14 Lines in it
- The text of this question.
- The text of just about any other question on StackExchange.
- Things that don't have a rhyme scheme. See Below

---

## Not A Sonnet

```
A man got on a boat
The boat was leaky
and had poor construction
For it was made by a one-eyed blind man
and his dumb intern
As soon as he got out of port
at the fort
it started to sink
eventually, it tanked.
And it capsized
If only that shipwright
wasn't so blind deaf and dumb
as microsoft tech support
That's not much support at all.
```

Comment: I think without dictionaries for rhymes and stresses this is probably not a good idea. Of course you can use some sort of accuracy ratio, but then you also need false positives, and you need a *lot* more examples than the few on the pages you've linked. But if you do this there's no requirement to actually recognise the sonnets by their rhymes and stresses - instead, I'm pretty sure, people will just regex golf the test sets.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I updated the requirements with an accuracy percentage, and added the option to use an API to look up terms from a dictionary.

Comment: 1. Test data which only covers one possible output isn't test data. I can write a program which always outputs `Y` in as little as one byte and it will pass all of the linked "test data", but it comes nowhere near to meeting spec. 2. Unless you specify *which* rhyme/stress dictionary to use, you can't guarantee that the test data is "correct".

Comment: @PeterTaylor I added examples of what is not a Sonnet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to say this, but it feels as though this task has a lot of individual parts, each of which could be quite tricky. Especiallly detecting rhymes/syllables/stresses, since words can be pronounced/stressed differently based on context. Also if you're using Shakespeare's sonnets I have no idea where to get rhyming and stress dictionaries for Elizabethan English...

Comment: To make this interesting, you'll need some interesting near-misses: non-sonnets that can't be detected by something simple like counting lines or words per line.

Comment: @xnor You mean a file with a that looks like a sonnet but has no rhyme.

Comment: Yes, for example. Or, one with rhyme by wrong rhythm. Or, one with nonsense characters that seem to "rhyme".

Comment: @Sp3000 You can just use modern english, or just base it on words that have similar endings.

Answer (score -3):

## Represent a Number in the Strangest Way You Can Think Of.. while staying under 8 unique characters

Your goal is to represent some numbers in the strangest way possible.

#### Rules:

- The result must be a number that can be used in the programming language like any other ordinary number. For instance, `<my expression> + 3` should return 3 more than the value of `<my expression>`.
- The code must be under 20 kilobytes. That's a rather large size for a number so you should be all set.
- The expression must have under 8 unique characters! The length of it can be as long you want, just keep it under 8 unique characters. `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is valid (if it works in the programming language) but `abcdefghijklm` isn't valid because it uses 8 or more unique characters.

#### Guidelines:

- The goal here is to represent a number in the strangest and most interesting way possible, so if I ask you to represent the number `35` it would be a good idea to respond with something more interesting than `35` or `12 + 23`.
- This isn't a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)! Feel free to make your code as long as you want, so long as it's under 20 kilobytes. Fancy code can look nice!
- The code doesn't need to support decimals (floats) but if it does, it will get 10 extra points (see below).
- The code also doesn't need to support negative numbers (for instance `-37`) but if it does, it will get 10 extra points (see below).
- Try to make your post follow the below:

#### Post format:

> ## Language
>
> Description
>
> #### 0
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 1
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 30
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 108
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 1337
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 1234567890
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### 3.1415 [10 bonus points if you can get this!]
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> #### -25 [10 bonus points if you can get this!]
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> ### Bonus numbers:
>
> ...

The points is equivalent to the number of votes on the answer plus 10 if it supports decimals with 10 more points if it supports negative numbers. Whoever has the highest points is considered the current winner. Have fun!

---

This is my first go at making a popularity contest so if you have any tips those would be appreciated.. :)

Comment: This is a great challenge... whoever downvoted this has to rethink their concept of code-restriction challenges...

Comment: Ah, thank you. :)

Comment: Updated again with negative numbers added (-25), as well as 1 and 0.

Comment: @Sp3000 8 unique chars, not 8 total.

Comment: @isaacg Didn't I state that?

Comment: @liam_ You did, the person I was responding to who deleted their comment missed it.

Comment: TBH, I think this is such a poor popcon that it can't be rescued, but if you want to at least make it clear what you're asking then: 1. You talk about representing "a" number, but also about "support[ing] decimals" and "support[ing] negative numbers". What exactly do you want? A function which maps numbers to code? But if so, the "Post format" makes no sense. 2. What is the code which has a 20kB limitation? Total for all the numbers listed in the "Post format"? Each individual number listed in the "Post format"? Something else? 3. Are the 8 distinct characters per number or for all numbers?

Answer (score -3):

## Stop the dance!

Your sister was at the hospital, but now she's fine, awfully, you lost a day of work, one of your most important days.

You work at your local television, and they have a contest, called "Stop the dance!", what is it about?: People is dancing, they have a big screen in the wall, while it says "Dance!", they have to dance, if it says "Stop!", they must stop, if you move, you lose.

You don't have internet at the studio, so you use some strange offline data sharing method. The day you weren't there, another programmer came, such a silly programmer! He made a "Reciever" program, basically, gets data, processes data and prints data in the Big Screen Wall.

The programmer was bored, so he made a way to get data, well, you don't know what way he choose! (Author comment: Let's assume he made all the possible ways. Cya.) Now you have to make a sender program, in any language, that sends data to that program using the protocol specified under this section.

You are an expert code golfer, so you decide that you must make the shortest code possible. (Another author comment: Any lang is allowed. Cya.)

## How did I came out with this idea?

Having a shower, my friend...

## Your task

You must make the shortest (and winner) code possible, that sends data to the reciever, using this protocol:

> The reciever must recieve:
>
> > `$displaytext:"<text here>";$instnm:<integer here>;`

$displaytext corresponds to what it is going to be displayed on the Big Screen Wall.

$instnm corresponds to the number of the instruction, the count of things displayed, starts from 1.

Your program may take an input, and send the data, in any way (except the ones in Rules) to the Reciever. Remember there's no internet.

The winner will be the user with shortest bytes of code.

## Rules

### As a good code golfer, you may not:

- You can't use program arguments to send the data.
- It must be an application.
- If you apply for the bonus, mind you have to make both programs, if not, just the sender.
- The string you have to send it has to be STRICT, no different ones, if not, unvalid answer. (I decided to call that "Strict JASON Protocol", get the joke?)

## Bonus

You can make the reciever program, and you get -1 byte. Not much, but k. (In bytes, you must not decrement your byte result, you must do: "n Bytes + Bonus")

## Example Input and Output

### Input:

> From Sender program:
>
> > Dance!
> >     or
> >     Stop!
> >
> > ### Protocol:
>
> Inbetween both commands
>
> > `$displaytext:"Dance!";$instnm:5`
> >
> > ### Output:
>
> In Reciever program:
>
> > Dance! (9)
> >     or
> >     Stop! (187)

## Overall objective:

Send data between two programs, without internet connection.

Edit: i can't post an example answer, because then i can give ideas of how to do this codegolf/puzzle, while the ideas are limited, i'm finding for the creativity of the user.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me to do.

Comment: It is pretty clear what is asking you to, is defined in Task (You must make the shortest (and winner) code possible, that sends data to the reciever, using this protocol), all the story and background is defined on Introduction. I dont see any hole on the post.

Comment: @TheCrimulo Example answer?

Comment: There is no Example, because you are just sending the same info you wrote in. If you type ´Dance!´, the output will be `Dance! (n)`, n being the number of the sequence. The idea isn't to read input, and append (n) to it. You have to make it, in anyway (except command args/internet), dropping out the enoded data (input in the protocol), and, if necessary, make a reciever program, the reciever program its a bonus that discounts 1 byte, also, it can help you making your sender smaller. I can, i.e., make a file with the info on it. As explained, the reciever will read it.

Answer (score -3):

## Biggest single character

This challenge is simple, its like the [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver) challenges we've had before where the goal is to produce the biggest output one can. But in this one, you can only use **one character in your code**.

You get no input, your code has to be a single **character** (not byte), and the person with the largest output in byte wins, ties broken by posting time.

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to which language has the biggest output stored in a predefined variable?

Comment: @DenkerAffe true. maybe i should make it 2 byte src code. that might allow some interesting stuff

Comment: I think I would raise the char amount a bit more to allow for some competition between the same language. Also you should keep in mind that this rules out every non-golfing language. While this should be allowed per meta consensus, I am not sure how much the community likes this.

Comment: G for pyth wins :D :D

Comment: Befunge & co. would probably win via infinite output. If output has to be finite though, I wouldn't consider this a very interesting challenge since it would just be one big language hunt.

Comment: Actually, `N` in Seriously wins. 11752 bytes output.

Comment: @Mego Vitsy wins. 0 bytes, 11752 bytes of output.

Answer (score -3):

## Alphabetization 101 (popularity contest)

Your task is to use all 52 letters of both the uppercase and lowercase alphabet, ONCE and ONCE only, and make a program.

You are free to use any other ASCII character more than once, or use a letter of the alphabet more than once if it's required for the language to function.

### Meta:

- Not sure if this has been done before.
- Any questions regarding the task?

Comment: Not really meta: Is there any place I can go to (like a chat or something) to post a question about BF? StackOverflow probably isn't suitable.

Comment: Come to [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)! :)

Comment: I would vote to close this as too broad. It's not a particularly interesting restriction per se, and it certainly doesn't make a good question without some restriction on the task to be performed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's why it's a popularity contest, though - it lets the people decide whether the program made is good or not. What WOULD be a good restriction on the task?

Comment: The [tag:popularity-contest] tag is not an excuse for a broad challenge. "Write a program that does anything..." is pretty much the definition of "too broad", regardless of any source code restriction put on the program. So at least you should choose a specific task. Could be anything really, but if it relates to the restriction it might be more interesting (e.g. a pangram checker). Even so, I agree with Peter that the restriction isn't particularly interesting. There are tons of languages where it's trivial to avoid unwanted letters and then include the remaining ones in a string or comment.

Answer (score -3):

## Why did I come to Sandbox?

I have a very specific challenge, and I wanted to see if it was too specific.

The challenge is to output "Valdosta ACM" using the shortest number of characters with the BrainF**k programming language.

I've noticed it isn't the norm to specify a programming language on this domain, so I've come here to get feedback on whether or not this is acceptable.

---

## Introduction

As a challenge to the members of my local Association for Computing Machinery(ACM) chapter, I asked them to produce the shortest [Brainf**k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) code that would output "Valdosta ACM".

This was a very fun challenge for all of our members, and we got very competitive! I was impressed with the solutions turned in, but I wondered if it was possible to beat our best solution. Surely it's possible, but who could do it?

## Challenge

Output the string "Valdosta ACM".

Stipulations:

- Use only the Brainf**k programming language (you can test your code [here](https://sange.fi/esoteric/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html))
- No input can be accepted by your program
- Your program must halt
- The space in the string must be ASCII character #032.

These are the ASCII values of each character, as they appear in the string, for convenience:

```
 086 097 108 100 111 115 116 097 032 065 067 077
```

The winner is determined by the shortest code, by character count.

## Example Input and Output

#### Input:

**NO** input is allowed

#### Output:

> Valdosta ACM

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Thanks for using the Sandbox. :) A few things to note: 1.) Generally we discourage language-specific challenges, 2.) typically code golf is scored by bytes rather than characters, and 3.) printing a fixed string like this would be insufficiently different from the Hello, World! challenge to avoid it being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Since I want to compare the results of my local competition with the results of the challenge here, is there anything I could change about the challenge to make it acceptable? I don't see a way to do this, but I was so excited about seeing if anyone here could do better than our coders. And thanks for the warm welcome! :)

Comment: You could look at Brainf**k solutions to other challenges (like [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494/3544)), and see if the techniques used there can help you improve your solution.

Comment: We also have a [tips question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/tips-for-golfing-in-brainfuck) that may be of interest.

Comment: Although this particular challenge is probably too similar to "Hello, World!" (as Alex pointed out), if you had a different challenge that you wanted to see solutions for in a specific language, you can still post it but just allow all languages to compete. If you don't see solutions in your specific language you can post a bounty for that language to encourage it.

Answer (score -3):

## The FitnessGram™ Code Golf Test

Same concept and rules to the well-known Rick Astley post a while back, only instead of using samples of various sizes, sample length is limited to what number sample it is.  [And different text for the program to write.](http://pastebin.com/knuvEDyA)
It's code golf, so standard loopholes apply, and fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Closed as a dupe. And/or unclear.

Comment: Paragraphs of text are boring for compression. Unless there's some particular structure in the text, the same techniques apply to all of them.

Comment: First off, thank you for using the Sandbox before posting on main. That said, I don't understand what your challenge is supposed to be: what is the sample length? What is a sample? In addition to that, if this challenge winds up being "print some fixed string" then it is a duplicate of the rick astley post, as the techniques used for compression will be identical.

Comment: we want to give them a challenge, not a flashback....

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score -3):

## Obfuscate your program

In this challenge, you must create a program which does something but you need to obfuscate it so that it becomes hard to understand (so don't explain it in your post).

It can accept anything as input and output anything.

**Score**

The shorter program (in bytes) which hasn't been understood wins.

**Example**

Can you guess what does this code calculate?

```
var t=1e5,s=t/1e4,n=s*0.1,i=n*s*7.5,r=!true,b=1,t='01'.split('').map(c=>parseInt(c)).concat(Array(i).join('.').split('.').map(m=>{a=r+b;(r=b)&&(b=a);return a})),t=t.join('').length,b=s,t=r,s=4+NaN;
```

**Rules**

- You should say what language you used
- You must not use any obfuscation tool

Comment: At a minimum, you should state an actual objective: "obfuscate a program that does *x*". Otherwise it's just too broad and will likely be closed as such. You'll also need something else to explain the scoring, since "shortest that isn't understood" seems odd to me. Understood when? How do you show that it hasn't been understood? Do you mean something like Cops and Robbers?.

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score -3):

### "01_firstHole" Challenge for Performance Golf

First there was code golf.  Now, there is Performance Golf.  FORE!

### Motivations

This is a crowd-sourced approach to easier and better performance troubleshooting.  Performance problems are everywhere, so java technicians need access to easy-to-use diagnostic tools at every step of the SDLC.

### How to play?

1. Start by [installing](https://github.com/eostermueller/performanceGolf/wiki/Install-and-Run) the live demonstrations of Java Performance Problems in this repo.
2. Pick one of the six holes of golf to play.  You can do this by picking one of the six numbered folders in the repo.  This particular codegolf.stackexchange.com challenge is for the `01_firstHole`.
3. One at a time, run the 'a' load test and the 'b' load test for the hole you selected.  The a & b tests are two different implementations of the same REST/SOA service.  See the 'installing' link, above, for how to run the tests.
4. Compare the performance of the two tests, a & b.  Which has better response time / throughput?
5. Using the least amount of tooling/instrumentation, identify the performance problem of the slower test.  Hook it up your self and run the tests.
6. At `codegolf.stackexchange.com`, there is one "Stack Exchange Challenge" for each hole of golf.  Post the following two things for your solution to that challenge:

   - Post a description of the tools/techniques you used to detect the performance problem. Must be detailed enough so that others can reproduce your work. Performance golf always compares two different loads -- a & b. The solution must identify the inefficient code in the slower of the two examples. It must also show the absence of that inefficient processing in the faster of the two examples.
   - Tally the number of strokes for your approach, using the "Scorecard" below.  All solutions must specify the # of strokes incurred, and it must be specified in the answer heading/title.
7. Upvote the solutions that best identify the performance problem **and** have the fewest strokes (see Scorecard, below).  Similar solutions on different platforms (Mac/Linux/MS-Win) deserve roughly the same number of upvotes.

### Scorecard

This scorecard determines the approach with the least amount of tooling/instrumentation.  Lowest score wins!

- 1 stroke if JVM restart is required to hook up your monitoring tool of choice.
- 1 stroke for any tool with any $$ licensing cost.
- 1 stroke for every separate install process. No strokes for JVM and pre-installed OS tools.
- 1 stroke for tools/techniques specific to a particular Database vendor.  Ex: Oracle AWR report.  Even ‘EXPLAIN PLAN’ solutions are proprietary.

### Example One -- zero strokes :-D

This example does not use this github repo, but it will give you the general idea.

[This solution](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/08/which-java-thread-consumes-my-cpu.html)  to solving a high CPU problem would get lowest=best instrumentatin score:  zero strokes.  Only JVM and OS tools are used (thread dump and top -H).  There are no tool license costs and a JVM restart was not required for the thread dump.

### Example Two -- 3 strokes :-(

This example also does not use this github repo, but it will give you the general idea of what we mean by the best troubleshooting with the least tooling/instrumentation.

A modern, commercial profiler (YourKit, JProfiler, etc...) would easily solve the high CPU problem in example 1.  But look how many strokes (1+1+1=4!) are taken off with this approach:
  * 1 stroke because a JVM restart is required to hook up the tool
  * 1 stroke because there are licensing costs.
  * 1 stroke to install profiling the tool

Comment: Answers in this site normally involve writing code, so this doesn't really appear to be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox! I do however, see some problems with this challenge. For one, I think you would need to clarify a lot of the stroke criteria, as something like "rarely used" is pretty subjective. In addition, there doesn't seem to be a way to enforce a person to not use a high level tool, and then after figuring out the problem finding it again with a more basic tool. Even further, why couldn't someone look at another answer and then reuse their data to get a better score? cont...

Comment: After all that, there doesn't seem to be an objective winning criterion, unless it is number of strokes. If number of strokes determines the winner, then won't there be many ties? I think you would need something more granular.

Comment: Sounds like I need to work on the "rarely used" part mentioned by @FryAmTheEggMan.  Regarding the same commenter's comments about the high-level tool and the basic tool.  That is part of the natural progression of monitoring.  We learn to do it one way, then we learn a better, less intrusive, less expensive way.  As long as the user of the basic tool is "detailed enough so that others can reproduce your work", who cares how much refinement was involved?

Comment: Regarding @FryAmTheEggman's question of "many ties".  I look at auction sites like eBay as reasonable crowd-sourced arbiters of value of a given object for sale.  I was hoping the voters would provide that kind of assessment, but I see where lack of objectivity could cause cronyism and perhaps other problems.  Could someone point me to codegolf tolerance/lack of for ties?  I'll try to work on that.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, you mentioned that my "rarely used" criteria was pretty subjective.  That's a good call, so just edited / removed that.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, the "many ties" concern could also looked at from a different perspective -- that Performance Golf will provide a very useful "catalog" of answers.  This "catalog" concept got 18 upvotes [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/should-solution-catalogs-be-on-topic-here).

Comment: The catalogue concept is [a failed experiment](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7686/194), and your mention of it is one of the reason why. "It's a catalogue question" should not be used to justify why a question should be closed even though it's off-topic and wouldn't have an effective scoring mechanism even if it were on-topic.

Answer (score -3):

## Make a Fork Bomb [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

<sup>*under construction, please constructively (no pun intended) criticize*</sup>

Create a program which forks itself at twice and exits, or forks itself once and idles. Whether it continues forever or exits is your choice. Forks can be OS forks or simply a command to relaunch the program.

### Rules

- No spoon bombs allowed, please.
- Don't make any assumptions about the location of the program.

---

## Bash, 10 chars

```
./$0|./$0&
```

Acts as a standard punching bag for other solutions.

---

## Microsoft Windows Batch file, 5 chars

```
 %0|%0
```

Anybody who beats this one gets a million internet points. (and maybe a bounty)

Comment: I assume that the downvote is because someone considers that this violates our policy on [malicious code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8877/194). I think it's borderline, but if it's on the right side of the border then the question has other issues. 1. Why fork itself at least twice? Surely forking once is enough for a fork bomb? 2. Define "*OS forks*" in a way which doesn't rely on the OS being POSIX. Or, better, remove that requirement: it seems to me to limit the languages permitted more than necessary for no benefit. 3. What's a spoon bomb? Google is not being helpful.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. the chat said it was fine 2. If you only fork once and exit, you have a constant amount of processes 3. Good idea. Any tips for windows forks? 4. it's a joke

Comment: I'm downvoting because I think it's close enough to malicious. A fork bomb can hang a computer.

Answer (score -3):

## Stump The Golfing Languages

This is the seed of an idea. I'm unclear on the details that might make it work.

I want people to submit answers in the form of a program in a "normal" language (defined how?), such that reproducing its functionality in a golfing language isn't much smaller. That is, I want to find the algorithms that Jelly and Pyth and Matl and such are not optimized for.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to make this work. Maybe cops and robbers? Maybe each entry just contains two programs, and comments are given to help golf the smaller one?

Comment: The only language that could possibly win is mathematica

Comment: Related: [Anti-golfscript anti-golf: create a task where GolfScript or J is outgolfed by your (conventional) lang closed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18761/12012)

Comment: It's very easy to come up with boring examples e.g. print this exact trace, reproduce the output of this random number generator, etc. I don't see any way to get interesting answers.

Comment: @feersum I'd probably disqualify errors and crashes and stacktrace outputs and such, and maybe all built-in non-trivial algorithms. Thanks for pointing those out.

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon you don't have to beat the golfing language to win. The winning entry will probably still have a shorter Jelly solution than Python (or whatever).

Comment: I don't know of any golfing languages where creating a simple webserver is possible. All this would be is finding a task that isn't normally required for when doing code-golf

Comment: I'm thinking of restricting it to algorithms and output, not stuff like network and file access.

Answer (score -3):

## Draw "Stack Exchange"

Stack Exchange has many site (159) and It has a logotype too.
Anyway, In this challenge you'll need to draw **Stack Exchange** in the most shortest way.

This is a code-golf. challenge.

### Rules

1. Have fun!
2. You've to draw Stack Exchange, you can't use Paint or something like that, you can't use libraries.

Comment: Challenges that start with "Most creative" are almost certainly guaranteed to not generate creative answers (or any answers for that matter)

Comment: @Fatalize I changed the challenge.

Comment: Now there is basically no interesting solution possible to the challenge, because there is no patterns in `Stack Exchange`. So all shortest solutions will to print that string directly or a compressed version of it.

Answer (score -3):

## Open the browser, polyglot edition. [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot)[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Your job is to open a browser window of the default browser to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com **in as many languages as possible**.

Your code must open the browser itself, and cannot rely on an open one.

### Rules

- Versions of the same language are considered a single language

Comment: Define "*default browser*" in the context of non-Windows OSes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Whatever browser the `open` command works with. There was a previous version of this challenge, it worked then.

Answer (score -3):

## Mad lads!

Inspired by the *[paper calculator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siawhQBRC8I)* episode of Numberphile.

Your challenge in this puzzle is to take in two two-bit (0-3) numbers and output the sum of the two numbers... using ordinary household objects.

Some possibilities of how this can be done:
[Dominoes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91472/56309)
[Paper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siawhQBRC8I)
[Marbles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIKah9aVlm4)
[music box](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-Programmable-Mechanical-Music-Box/) (+ some helpers..)

### Input:

input must always be involving two sets of two-bit integers, which can be represented by anything you like, so long as the cardinality of the representations is the same.

### Output:

The output should be a single 3-bit integer which represents the addition of the two inputs.

### Rules:

- your device cannot have the capability to connect to the internet in
  any way (sorry, this also disqualifies carrier pigeons). Your device
  must also not be able to perform this function alone (eg a
  calculator).
- It must be *somewhat* original. put your own twist on it!
- though, your entry can be alive (does your dog add??), so long as your entry is not in discomfort.
- Pictures are required for each entry to show how it works. videos would be better, but aren't required!
- The sole function of your machine does not have to be adding, it can do other
  things as well. This means that older projects that may serve a
  slightly different function are welcome, so long as they meet the
  rules stated above.
- Your device can be as simple or as complex as you like, so long as it doesn't get to a point where it's completely esoteric.

### Judging:

You will be judged based on ease of use, ease of understanding, as well as originality! This means that entries should be easily explained, used, and be unique in some way.

This is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the most upvotes wins! good luck!

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a programming challenge. Once we start leaving the realm of a computer-based programming paradigm, a challenge becomes more difficult to test, replicate, and verify. Plus, something done with Dominoes, for example, may not "run" to completion 100% of the time, and in my opinion that makes it non-deterministic.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10151/34718. TLDR, if you want to program with dominoes, find or create a domino simulator where programs can be scored in bytes. Instead of marbles, use [Marbelous](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Marbelous).

Comment: @mbomb007 what about papers, and counting dogs? This isn't a code golf, it's a popularity contest

Comment: Popcons still require the use of programming *languages*. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028/34718. See both linked meta questions. What you are trying to do is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm not sure you linked the correct thing. I have found no reference of popularity contests in your recent link..

Comment: Rules and meta consensus apply to *all* challenges, not just code-golf.

Comment: Popcons should be held to a *higher* standard than other questions, not a lower one as your comments imply.

Answer (score -3):

### 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

I teb ev'uoy lla draeh tuoba eht doog 'lo 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw. Llew ti os sneppah taht I emoc morf na evitanretla esrevinu - eht esrevinu erehw ew etirw gnihtyreve ni esrever! Ew peek eht snoitisop fo lanigiro hguoht. Siht osla snaem reporp noitazilatipac fo tsrif (ekil rettel ni siht txet). Ruoy egnellahc si ot etirw a margorp taht stuptuo eht lausu 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw, tub ni esrever (ni ruo egaugnal uoy dluow llac ti 99 bottles of beer on the wall). **Siht si a ytiralupop tsetnoc, os teg evitaerc dna yrt ot sserpmi eht dworc. Doog kcul!**

> I bet you've all heard about the good ol' 99 bottles of beer on the wall. Well it so happens that I come from an alternative universe - the universe where we write everything in reverse! We keep the positions of original though. This also means proper capitalization of first letter(like in this text). Your challenge is to write a program that outputs the usual 99 bottles of beer on the wall, but in reverse (in our language you would call it 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw). **This is a popularity contest, so get creative and try to impress the crowd. Good luck!**

Elpmas fo derised tuptuo:

> Sample of desired output:

---

> 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw, 99 selttob fo reeb. Ekat eno nwod dna
>   ssap ti dnuora, 89 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw.
>
> 89 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw, 89 selttob fo reeb. Ekat eno nwod dna
>   ssap ti dnuora, 79 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw.
>
> ...
>
> 1 elttob fo reeb no eht llaw, 1 elttob fo reeb. Ekat eno nwod dna ssap
>   ti dnuora, on erom selttob fo reeb no eht llaw.
>
> On erom selttob fo reeb no eht llaw, on erom selttob fo reeb. Og ot
>   eht erots dna yub emos erom, 99 selttob fo reeb no eht llaw.

Comment: There's no need for the reversed text in the description - it distracts the viewer from the challenge at hand.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp I wanted to make this a bit more "unique" and "immersing", so I thought about giving the reversed description(I like it). I also included original text(although in spoilers), but I was also wondering about distracting readers. Do you have some other idea on how to keep both versions without making it look obscure?

Comment: 1. This should not be a [tag:popularity-contest]. 2. It's fundamentally a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64198/194 . 3. If you're going to muck around with the question text, write a program that mucks it around correctly. "*elpmaS*" doesn't follow the specified transformation rule.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. why not? 2. It's not. You can't simply reverse, and counting is a bit different.

Comment: *Do X creatively* popularity contests have fallen out of scope. This will get closed if posted on main.

Comment: @Dennis Damn, too bad. I guess I won't be posting it then, it's boring "shortest code".

Comment: What does this add to the original '99 bottles of beer on the wall'?

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score -3):

## Best n out of 2n - 1

#### Challenge:

This one should be relatively simple.  Output this exact text:

```
Best [n] out of [2n - 1].
```

given n as an input.

#### Input:

Just the integer n, can be from stdin or as an argument.  n will always be greater than 0.

#### Output:

The exact text above.  Trailing spaces/newlines are allowed.

#### Rules:

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.  Standard loopholes are forbidden.

#### Meta:

Is this too simple?  What other tags should be included, [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)?

Comment: Seems like a dupe of [2spooky4me](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62350/14215), just with a different operator.

Comment: Your wording specifies "this exact text" while I think your intent is "Best 5 out of 9." or the like.

Comment: @Geobits Aha, I knew I remembered a similar challenge.  Just forgot the exact name, so I thought maybe I was just imagining things after I tried to find it.  My bad.

Answer (score -3):

## Google Home / Amazon Echo - Turing complete?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Your challenge is to try to make a turing machine based on Google Home and Amazon Echo, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfCfTYZJWtI).

You must describe how to set up the machine, and how to give it input.

You must also describe a program for integer addition. It should compute 1+1 to be 2, 200+55 = 255, 200+56 = 0, and so on for all other combinations of 2 8-bit integers.

Comment: It's basically not possible...

Comment: VTC as unclear and too broad.  What are you even expecting as an answer?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk A set of commands that send the 2 computers into infinite loop, reading commands endlessly from a list of commands for the other to run, eventually processing a computer program and finally calculating the answer to the universe.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Why not? I mean other than that we have yet to prove their turing-completeness.

Comment: @SoniEx2 so only 1 of each computer? And what defines a command?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk A command is anything that starts with "Hey google" or "Alexa" and triggers a successful response on either of the computers.

Comment: Are we allowed to program the Echo and Google device? If so this is trivial. If we're supposed to construct a sentence that winds up having the devices compute using existing services like the calendar in the video, there are plenty of web sites that can process a variety of languages and read back the solution. Echo has basic math built in.

Comment: I really hope this can be tweaked into a challenge because the youtubes would be awesome.

Comment: @wyldstallyns tbh I have no idea what I'm doing... But yes, you're allowed to program both of them.

Comment: A question should ideally be self-contained. In this case the APIs for Google Home (whatever that is) and Amazon Echo (whatever that is) probably won't fit in the question, but an overview and links to the APIs would.

Comment: @PeterTaylor This isn't a matter of APIs. This is a matter of voice commands.

Answer (score -3):

## Make a Simple GUI application

I have made a simple glade layout. The chalenge is to remake it in as few bytes as possible.

The glade file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Remake me!</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">hello</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">world</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: This probably doesn't break any rules, but it also doesn't seem that fun.  It would be preferable if it was a more substantial task than simply golfing the code you already wrote.

Answer (score -3):

#### Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock

This game is from The Big Bang Theory, an extended version of the classic [Rock Paper Scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock%E2%80%93paper%E2%80%93scissors) game.

**Objective**

To create a full program that I can run to play Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock against an "AI". The opponent ("AI") will pseudo-randomly choose their option after receiving user input.

The program must be run with user input of the following;

```
| Input     | Meaning   |
|-------    |---------- |
| R         | Rock      |
| P         | Paper     |
| S         | Scissors  |
| L         | Lizard    |
| SP        | Spock     |
```

The game is played with the following rules that Sheldon tells us;

> Scissors cuts Paper
>
> Paper covers Rock
>
> Rock crushes Lizard
>
> Lizard poisons Spock
>
> Spock smashes Scissors
>
> Scissors decapitates Lizard
>
> Lizard eats Paper
>
> Paper disproves Spock
>
> Spock vaporises Rock
>
> Rock crushes Scissors

[image]

Once you've taken user input, psuedo-randomly chosen the AIs option, you must output either "`Player wins (<<user_input>> vs <<ai_input>>)`" or "`AI wins (<<user_input>> vs <<ai_input>>)`". In the event of a tie (both the user and AI choose the same options), you must output "`It's a tie`"

**Sample Runs**

```
//Player chooses Scissors (S)
//AI chooses Paper (P)
$ php -f rpslsp.php S
Player wins (S vs P)

//Player chooses Spock (SP)
//AI chooses (R)
$ php -f rsplsp.php SP
Player wins (SP vs R)

//Player chooses Lizard (L)
//AI chooses Scissors (S)
$ php -f rsplsp.php L
AI wins (L vs S)

//Player chooses Lizard (L)
//AI chooses Lizard (L)
$ php -f rsplsp.php L
It's a tie
```

**Rules**

- Standard loopholes apply.
- The computer must choose an input at random (pseudo random) so that on each program run, the AI chooses (in a perfect world) a different input and that each input has the same percentage of being chosen.

---

This is code-golf so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: "A full program" means that we're not allowed to return the result from a function? Must it be a full program??

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder What I mean is we are able to run it in environments like TIO or REPL.it

Comment: 1. It's not true that the game is from BBT. BBT made a cultural reference to a preexisting game. 2. The output spec is incomplete because it doesn't say what to do in the case of ties.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, I've only known the game exists because of TBBT, though the origin of the game doesn't really affect anything except maybe tread on the toes of some serious competitive RSPLSP players. Thanks for reminding me about it being a tie.

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35079/16766). [Less closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12090/16766).

Answer (score -3):

## Find the min swaps for order one powerset for a List

The question it is write one powerset function and one sort function
tha minimize the swaps for doing one order with this compare function
on powerset of the List A

```
cmp(a,b) -- a and b are subset of the list A
    if sizeof a > sizeof b then (swap a and b; return)
    if sizeof a < sizeof b than return
    for i in 1..(sizeof a) repeat
         for j in 1..(sizeof A) repeat
               if a[i]==A[j] then return
               if b[i]==A[j] then (swap a and b; return)
```

the result of this compare function on the sets wuold be the follow:

```
(15) -> powSet([1,2,3])
   (15)  [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
(16) -> powSet([3,2,1])
   (16)  [[],[3],[2],[1],[3,2],[3,1],[2,1],[3,2,1]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
```

note that order depend not from the number element, 
but on the position on the start List A=[1,2,3]

```
(17) -> powSet([1,2,3,4,5,6])
   (17)
   [[], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [2,3],
    [2,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [4,5], [4,6], [5,6], [1,2,3],
    [1,2,4], [1,2,5], [1,2,6], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,3,6], [1,4,5], [1,4,6],
    [1,5,6], [2,3,4], [2,3,5], [2,3,6], [2,4,5], [2,4,6], [2,5,6], [3,4,5],
    [3,4,6], [3,5,6], [4,5,6], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,4,5],
    [1,2,4,6], [1,2,5,6], [1,3,4,5], [1,3,4,6], [1,3,5,6], [1,4,5,6],
    [2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,6], [2,3,5,6], [2,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5],
    [1,2,3,4,6], [1,2,3,5,6], [1,2,4,5,6], [1,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,5,6],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
```

Win the one that minimize the swaps for order the powerset of the follow list

```
[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

## Patterns match for composed expression

If we have one math expression B(x) 
[that mean in B appear x]
[math expression is one expression where appear only symbols for function and operator of mathematics that are ok for type and compose ]
Find the max lengt subexpression g(x)
of B contain x such that

```
B(x)=f(g(x))
```

And f(y) and g(x) are both math expression.

## Find Max for a function in one interval

R is the set of real numbers.
Is given a function f:A->R from set A (⊆ R) to the R, continue and derivable in one close interval

```
 [a, b]⊆A
```

Write the shortest program for find

```
 max{f(x): x in [a,b]}
```

knowing the function f(x) derivable in the interval [a,b]. The solution has to be correct at last until the V digit after the float point, and for all functions f that has 10 value max in which f'(x)= 0 in [a, b]. codegolf tag

## On Riemann Zeta function domain

If `Zeta:C->C` is the Riemann Zeta function, we give the set:

```
 W={b: 0<b<100 and Re(Zeta(0.5+i*b))=-Im(Zeta(0.5+i*b))}
```

Where `Re()` return the real part of its argument, and `Im()` return the imaginary part of its argument.

**It is requested** to calculate one approximation of each element of `W`; this means here all b in float numbers with b in `0..100` such way

```
  abs(Re(Zeta(0.5+i*b))+Im(Zeta(0.5+i*b)))<0.0001
```

at last, to put all together in a array or list or set of float.

One can note that the below set of zeros for the Riemann function is a subset of above `W` set.

```
 {b: 0<b<100 and Zeta(0.5+i*b)=0}
```

**Some test**

Some numbers b approssimation to solution of equation

```
Re(Zeta(0.5+i*x))+Im(Zeta(0.5+i*x))=0
```

the ones that are approssimation to solution of equation `Zeta(0.5+i*x)=0` too

```
[14.134725, 21.022039, 30.424876, 32.935061, 37.58617815, 40.918719, 43.327073, 48.00515, 49.773832]
```

the ones not approssimation to solution of equation `Zeta(0.5+i*x)=0` too

```
[12.458493623791109003, 24.351346882420215577, 28.716611773969890307]
```

The code more short in bytes that find all these approssimations of element of the set `W` wins...

Code golf tag

Comment: You're going to need to phrase this better and be more precise about what you're asking for. Currently, this sounds a little bit like a homework question.

Comment: This is also formatted improperly.

Comment: This appears to permit hard-coding the output, which is generally a sign of a bad question. Why not parameterise it?

Comment: I think now I ' m clear... What is not clear or ambiguous?

Comment: possibly a little too much difficult... there are numbers that seems solutions but if i increase digits they are just wrong....

Comment: Also, it's "approximation".

Comment: Being (continuous and) differentiable is quite a weak constraint. There are e.g. nasty functions which are differentiable but whose derivative is not integrable.

Comment: One continue function in one close interval [a, b] has max and min

Comment: So for the order a PowerSet of one list is all clear...

Answer (score -3):

## Fastest Compiling Fibonacci Sequence [compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler) [fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci) [fastest-compiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-compiling)

Your task is to create a program which takes one numerical input and outputs all numbers in the Fibonacci sequence up to that point. However, you will not be scored on its bytecount or how many upvotes it gets. You will be scored on how quickly the compiler can compile it.

---

### Rules

- Of course, compiled languages are the only languages allowed.
- All answers are tested on an Amazon EC2 instance with an Intel Xeon at 2.4GHz, about 1 GB of ram, and Amazon Linux installed. You can time your program on an equivalent machine, but I will compare results.
- Your program is allowed to produce warnings when compiled, but it should work properly when run.
- Compile time is tested with the `time` command, and "real" time is used for the final score.
- If I need to comment the amount of time you took, you should add it to your answer.
- Of course, standard loopholes are *strictly* disallowed.

---

This is [fastest-compiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-compiling), so may the cleverest optimization win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: For a trivial challenge like this the compilation time is going to be dominated by noise: whether the compiler is in the disk cache is going to be more important than the code submitted.

Comment: To make compile times longer, you could require for the compiled program to work in `O(1)`, or constant time. Then, the compiler will have to hardcode the entire sequence (up to a point specified by you, e.g. the largest 32- or 64-bit Fibonnaci number), which could make for interesting template-based programming optimization.

Comment: @Sanchises, not true. Binet's formula will do the job in O(1).

Comment: @PeterTaylor of course. So, another sequence which is proven not to have a direct formula could make this challenge possibly salveagable.

Answer (score -3):

## Be typically flexible efficiently

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Write a short function that returns outputs of different types in a non-boring way. If *L* is the length of your code and *T* is the number of different types returned, your score is (*T*−1)/*L.* The highest score wins.

- The function must take exactly one argument and be deterministic, i.e., the output depends only on the input.
- Obviously your programming language must have an official notion of *type,* by which each object has a unique, clearly identified type.
  Typically this would manifest in a `type` or `typeof` function returning an object’s type.
  Also, it must obviously allow functions to have differently typed returns.
  If there are many separate typing systems in your language, you have to pick one (conforming with the above) and stick to it.
- The function must not employ any conditional constructs or other language features whose primary purpose is to handle logic, such as `if` statements, loops, or logical conjunctions. (Obviously, employed predefined functions need not adhere to this.)
- All inputs needed to produce the outputs used for scoring as well as any elements of [container structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type)) must adhere to the following:

  - They are all of the same type.
  - If they are functions or otherwise callable (and actually called in your program), they must consistently return objects of the same type.
  - They must not be classes, type identifiers, or similar.
  - If they are strings, they are treated (with respect to these rules) as any obvious interpretation of them as code, class names, or similar.
  - If they are containers themselves, their elements must adhere to these rules when taken together.

  So, e.g., in Python the following are invalid:

  ```python
  a = lambda i: [ 0, 0., [], {}, (0), {0} ][i]
  b = lambda i: [ int, float, list, dict, tuple, set ][i]()
  c = lambda i: [ [0], [0.], [[]], [{}], [(0)], [{0}] ][i][0]
  d = eval   # using "0", "0.", "[]", "{}", … as input
  e = lambda i: eval( ["0","0.","[]","{}","(0)","{0}"][i] )
  ```

  This also applies to containers generated during by the function during its execution. (Obviously, this does not apply to such objects if used internally by employed predefined functions.)

---

## Valid (ungolfed) example

Python:

```python
def f(i):
    return sum([2.][0:i])
```

For this we have:

```
f(0) == 0
type(f(0)) == int
f(1) == 2.0
type(f(1)) == float
```

This makes use of the fact that the `sum` of an empty iterable (like `[2.][0:0]`) is `0`.

---

## Sandbox questions

- I am pondering whether I should replace a portion of the rules with a catch-all like:

  > If whatever trick you use to acquire *n* types of output can be used to obtain *n*+1 types of output, it is invalid. (If *n*+1 just doesn’t work because *n* is the total number of types in your language, this doesn’t count either.)

  Obviously, this would lessen the chance of any boring loopholes, but it would also be more likely to be subject to interpretation. Do you think this is a good idea?
- Did I miss any obvious loopholes that would make this challenge boring?
- This challenge was mainly done with Python in mind, but I seen no reason why it should not extend to other programming languages (with a suitable typing system). Are there any obvious pitfalls with other languages that I should consider?
- Are there any other appropriate tags for the question?

Comment: This seems like an interesting challenge at its core, but there are a lot of gotchas. Is indexing into a tuple considered a logical construct? For example, in PowerShell, you can put a Boolean into the index and it will automatically cast to `0` or `1` to get a pseudo-ternary operation. Are languages like Java allowed to use reflection? Etc.

Comment: Also in a language like R (my most familiar language), there are really only 7 `types` as given by `typeof()` but there are numerous classes which can be found by `class()`. That being said, every instance of an R class is really `list` when `typeof()` is called on it. [see this, for example](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6SyIDU/TaMoJ1XDUFOTKzknsbgYzoNK5iaWFGVWaBjqACFcDZogVGlaYnJJfhGSUQiB//8B). Basically, you'll have to make a decision for every language submitted on "a suitable typing system"

Comment: @AdmBorkBork: *Is indexing into a tuple considered a logical construct?* – No, handling logic is not the primary purpose of this feature. I also do not see this as a problem since a tuple is an iterable and thus its elements would have to be of the same type. (Such pseudo-choosing operations are exactly the reason why I imposed that rule.) — *Are languages like Java allowed to use reflection?* – I only briefly looked into this, but I don’t see a how this could pose a loophole.

Comment: @Giuseppe: *`(T-1)/L` rather than `(T-1)/C`* – corrected, thanks. — *Basically, you'll have to make a decision for every language submitted on "a suitable typing system"* – I added a note that you can pick one and stick to it in that case. Would this pose any problems with your example (R)?

Comment: 1. A PowerShell tuple is not an iterable. 2. Plenty of languages have duck typing. That's a clear notion of type, but it has the potential to trivialise this question in the same way that reflection does. E.g. in JavaScript `function f(s){var o={};o[s]=f;return o}` 3. The Java method you should be looking at is `Class.forName`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: 1. Okay, let me generalise this to *containers.* 2. I am familiar with duck typing from Python but I don’t see how this provides a loophole. Your JavaScript example always returns something of type `object` IIUC. 3. From what I just learnt, that seems to be a special case of interpreting strings as code.

Comment: 2. "*If there are many separate typing systems in your language, you have to pick one and stick to it.*" I'm using duck typing: your objection is using prototype-based typing. 3. No, it takes a string which is the name of a type and instantiates an object of that type using its public 0-ary constructor.

Comment: Given that so many approaches are disallowed,  can you add a simple example or two of a valid approach?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: 2. I get what you are going at now, but I would not consider *duck typing* a clear typing system in the sense that every object has a unique type (I edited to clarify) – if you so wish, it is the absence of such a system. 3. I gathered that, but how is that not interpreting a string as code? Anyway, I edited that criterion to be more inclusive.

Comment: @user2390246: I added an example.

Comment: I don't think the edits unambiguously resolve the issues. 2. I can write a `typeof` function in JavaScript which produces an array of the properties of an object. 3. It's more like a `defaultdict` lookup than `eval`. And I don't see how "*these strings are subject to all rules*" unambiguously prohibits reflection.The contents of the string are characters: the string is not a valid statement or expression, and its contents can't really be said to *have* a type.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: 2. *I can write a `typeof` function in JavaScript which produces an array of the properties of an object.* – Words fail me. Let’s stick to official type systems (I edited). — 3. *unambiguously prohibits reflection* – My goal isn’t to prohibit reflection (which is probably fuzzy anyway), but only exploits thereof that make this challenge boring. I restructured the rules and extended them in a way that I hope will clearly cover `Class.forName` and any other boring exploits.

Answer (score -3):

**Puzzle:**

- Make a program that draws the following figure line by line.
- Your program should wait for one-second(it can be longer, just has to be a noticable difference) after drawing each line.
- Your program can **only** draw line by line (you cannot jump to another point or re-draw over a line)
- Given a positive integer `n`, produce an art image of the below drawing
- The angle measures should always be the same (regardless of `n`'s value)
- However, each line's length should be `150*n` pixels
- You only need to account for when `n` = 1, `n` = 2, `n` = 3

[image: example]

**Specifications:**

if **n=1:**

- length = 150 pixels

if **n=2:**

- length = 300 pixels

if **n=3**

- length = 450 pixels

.

.

**Answering**
- Name the language you used followed by its bytes

Example:

> **Java (swing), 500 bytes**

.

**Scoring**

- This is code golf. Lowest score (bytes) wins.
- [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.

Good luck!

Comment: You haven't solved the obvious issue "You can't have an equilateral triangle with angles of 45-45-90." (comment from [deleted challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145978/drawing-a-figure-without-lifting-up-your-pen)) The sandbox is only helpful if you listen to people who suggest changes, really.

Comment: I'm not sure what we're being asked to draw. Just the black figure? The black figure and the annotations?

Answer (score -3):

I have seen many a trivial answer in jelly, so i wish to propose:

**Challenge: A non-trivial answer**

- Input two strings
- If the two strings are integers and are equal, output a truthy value.
- Otherwise, output a falsy value.

**Clarifications**

- You may receive non-integer inputs.
- You will never receive an integer that is outside the bounds [-2³¹, 2³¹).
  Rules
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.

**Scoring:**

- This is not your standard code-golf
- the winner person who posts the longest program.
- an entry is invalidated if someone posts a shorter program in the same language.

Comment: Note: i don't believe that this is code-bowling, as only the shortest program in any language is eligible; this is more about finding an obscure language in which the task is actually hard to do, rather than obscure languages where the task is too easy.

Comment: Easy win for [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary).

Comment: what a horrible way of representing a program, yeah... any type of 'longest sensible program' task is not so helpful.

Comment: @Dennis do you think that restricting to languages that have won a standard code-golf challenge in 2017 would help? It does seem that if we have to start putting in language or other implementation restrictions, then this isn't worth posting. Oh well. guess this stays on the proposal board.

Answer (score -3):

**Golf This Question**

Your program should output to STDOUT the full text of this question as it appears on your screen, so no HTML. This includes the title and the body. Please do not edit this question whatsoever so-as to keep it the same for all programs.

**No** reading the text from a file or the internet

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

**Sandbox**
Is this a good question? Is there anything I should clarify?

Comment: [similar but obviously different](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55857/print-this-question-%E2%86%93) since it requires the markdown.

Comment: You should add some rules and winning criteria (which would increase the length of the question, but oh well)

Comment: I'm not sure what much this adds beyond the typical KC challenges, and thus it's likely to be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I guess OP means to allow access to the internet, in which case it's very different, but I'm not sure... If so, it's basically a challenge about parsing html, or get the result directly from the API (if that's possible).

Comment: Include tag about Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score -3):

## Shortest code to draw a png from stdin

### Rules :

- You’re free to use any image library you want as long as the image library is designed in the same language as your answer.
- The image should be displayed in an Xorg or wayland window or a console framebuffer.
  If you’re displaying to a window, you don’t need to create any windows control *(in that case the programs ends with CTRL+C)*.
- The stdin stream doesn’t eof. so the only way to get the image size is to parse png data. Once the image had been displayed, /dev/stdin should be closed.
- Your answer shouldn’t crash on random data.

The answer using the fewest bytes wins !

Comment: Way too easy for some languages and way too hard for others. And how would I do it if my language can't produce graphical output? What if I have neither STDIN nor STDOUT?

Comment: @StephenLeppik : the point of my question is to suggest that language choice is restricted to languages that can run on Unix systems supportting screening. I don’t know too easy answers, but `libpng16` along Xorg libraries should make it possible in a few line of code.

Comment: Restricting it to such a small list of languages is a good way of alienating half the site.

Comment: @StephenLeppik : It just basically, restrict to all languages which can write a hello word. Writing to a framebuffer is just as easy as to write a raw image in device file which opens like a normal file so this doesn’t matter. I’d rather say the list of language that can print a Hello world on Linux or ʙꜱᴅ is huge but not small.

Comment: Believe it or not, displaying an image is not a capability that directly follows from being able to print text…

Comment: @UnrelatedString that’s because it’s not possible to do it from text I’m asking this. But this is defintely like writing to a file.

Answer (score -3):

## Hack Stack!

Your challenge is to create a code snippet in javascript that will upvote your answer when run. This should not be possible, but maybe it is. We'll see!

### Rules

Standard Loopholes are not allowed.

You should not auto-downvote other answers.

Do not manually upvote any ansewer, please!

The first one to write code that also accepts the answer when it is run by me will remain accepted.

### For discussion:

Is this even a valid challenge?

Comment: I'm a newbie here but I think this is exactly the most dangerous place to ask for code to run on your PC. Too many clever obfuscators, golfers and [meta-tag:underhanded] practitioners to trust.

Comment: Maybe, instead of requesting submissions do something that is (1) possibly impossible, (2) illegal, and (3) unsafe to run on your browser, have the submission *try* to upvote the answer (even though this might not work)

Comment: I think this counts as asking for malicious code, which is against [the site rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for telling me this is illegal and against the rules. I wasn't thinking of it that way. Not a good challenge, then. Should I delete it, or keep it there so that other people with similar ideas can see it?

Answer (score -3):

## Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

So christmas is comming and carols are on the radio all day. Jose Feliciano's *Feliz Navidad* song is a good example of this. Your task is to print the entire (and repetitive) song.

[Lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/josefeliciano/feliznavidad.html):

```
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad
A-ha!

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas
I want to wish you a merry Christmas from the bottom of my heart

Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad
Feliz navidad, prospero año y felicidad
```

RULES:

- Default loopholes are forbidden.
- Default I/O.
- Programs or functions are acceptable.
- You MUST include the ñ character in the *año* word.
- You can print it in lowercase, uppercase or sentence case.
- Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Hi there! I'm the downvoter. I'm not sure this adds much to the site beyond other recent KC challenges, and it is very likely to be closed as a dupe of either "RickRoll" or "Writing Lines in Detention" as it's currently written. What can you describe about this challenge that adds to the site?

Comment: For reference -- [RickRoll challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043/42963) -- [Write lines in detention](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40206/42963)

Comment: Well, it may be a mix of those two challenges but what I found mainly interesting to see is how the users manage to put the ñ character and the "A-ha!" line that is the unique part of the song.

Comment: That ñ is just one byte in Win1252, which most answers will probably output in. I don't think this adds anything, personally, and cannot recommend posting it.

Answer (score -3):

### Ultimate crackpot

In minimum number of ASCII bytes, write a plain text "physics research article" in English that scores each item in [The Crackpot Index](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html) at least once.

<sub>I'm not sure if such thing is on-topic here or on the Puzzling.</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is on topic on either of those sites. I'm not sure there is a StackExchange site that this would be on-topic. it would have to be some sort of parody writing site similar in style to uncyclopedia or something

Comment: I think it's a funny idea to achieve as many of these as possible but it's not really on topic here and it would not be possible in plain text to, for example, mail the paper to someone (#12)

Comment: A lot of these aren’t very objective either.

Answer (score -3):

## Same code, different work

Write a code in a language that do these few things:

1. Input a positive integer `n`, check whether it's a prime. (2 -> true, 5 -> true, 8 -> false)
2. Input an integer `n>1`, output an array with fewest positive prime as element, where the sum of the array is `n`. (2 -> [2], 5 -> [5], 6 -> [3, 3], 8 -> [3, 5] or [5, 3])
3. Input an integer `n`, output `sum(n mod i, for i=1 to n)`. (2 -> 0, 5 -> 4, 8 -> 8)

Your code should theoretically solve all legal `n`, but in practive up to 1000 is enough

Shortest code in bytes win.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: The third task: shouldn't it be 2 -> 0 (2 % 1 = 0; 2 % 2 = 0). And you should probably decompress the specs a bit. And isn't there a polyglot tag?

Comment: There IS a polyglot tag. Although same languages are OK, that can probably only work with different versions (e.g. Python 2 vs Python 3), which seems to be considered a polyglot too.

Answer (score -3):

Write a program who return the current month.

### The Rules

- The result needs to be correct even if the program is run **in the future**.
- It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins!

---

### Optional

Add an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language.

---

<sup>It's my first code-golf idea I'm fully open to improving it with more experienced users.</sup>

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)

Comment: That's usually a problem with trivial challenges. If this isn't a duplicate of an existing challenge, I predict it will get a lot of answers very quickly, many of which will be very short golfing language solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114787/its-current-year-already-folks-go-home

Comment: Nope, still not all that good.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Hm, what can I improve so?

Comment: IMO you're wasting your time trying to improve this. Delete it and try to come up with something which is inherently interesting.

Comment: Write a program who return the current month should probably change that to Write a program which return the current month. what do you think. Also JSYK : This is a one line task for languages like JS and Ruby. So you should probably ban those

Comment: good point. I guess leave it as is.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Easier challenges get shorter solutions. If you don't want to see short solutions (no idea why), write hard challenges.

Comment: @user202729 : I never said I don't want short solutions. But these aren't much of a challenge. For example even a ten year old kid would be able to solve this in JavaScript using built in's. in all a total of 10 chars spent and 2 seconds. Not fun. Challenges that make you stop and think and actually work for them are best. Of course feel free to disagree.

Answer (score -3):

## Output Infinity (updated v2)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

### Challenge

Output the following **infinity symbol**:

```
         ∞∞infinity                         ∞infinity                   
     infinity∞∞infinity                 infinity∞∞infinity              
   infinity∞∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity           infinity∞∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity            
  infinity        ∞∞infinity      ∞∞∞∞∞infinity        ∞∞∞∞∞∞∞          
 ∞∞∞∞∞                 ∞∞∞∞∞∞∞  ∞∞∞infinity               ∞∞∞∞∞         
 ∞∞∞                      ∞∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity                   ∞∞∞         
∞∞∞                         ∞∞infinity                       ∞∞∞        
∞∞∞                       ∞∞infinity                         ∞∞∞        
 ∞∞∞                    ∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity                      ∞∞∞         
 ∞∞∞∞∞               ∞∞∞infinity  ∞∞∞∞∞∞∞                 ∞∞∞∞∞         
  infinity       ∞∞∞∞∞infinity     ∞∞∞infinity        infinity          
    infinity∞∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity           infinity∞∞∞∞∞∞∞infinity           
      infinity∞∞infinity                infinity∞∞∞infinity             
           ∞infinity                        ∞∞∞infinity
```

### Rules

- No input.
- Output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Any number of **trailing spaces** at the end of each line is allowed.
- Any number of **trailing new lines** at the end of the shape is permitted.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an on-line testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: need some comments for down-vote...

Comment: If the challenge's goal is -- as I understand it -- to output one of the five objects, in most languages that would result in an optimal submission of something along the lines of `print("∞")`. A rather boring but valid submission to a challenge that effectively asks to print a single unicode character.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you're allowing multiple outputs, some of which are interesting (4-5), some of which are trivial (1-3). As @JonathanFrech suggests, for a [tag:code-golf] challenge, everyone is going to chose a trivial output for shortness. Alternate ideas: Input an integer 1-5, output the corresponding form of infinity. Or perhaps narrow to just output option #4 (or an even larger, fancier ASCII infinity), and make it a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] question.

Comment: I would even say that this challenge in its current form should be tagged [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]. If you decide to go in the direction @BradC suggested, you could maybe also consider to incorporate the challenge's theme into your challenge rather than posting yet another Kolmogorov complexity challenge. Something along the lines of infinitely outputting the ASCII art or taking two numbers as input, dividing them and producing the infinity symbol when the second one is zero.

Comment: I don't think this is anyhow related to math. Only "inspired by math", maybe.

Comment: Now -- is there any exploitable pattern in the output such that it should not be closed as a dupe of "We're no stranger to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I"?

Comment: @user202729 No, there is no predefined specific pattern, I prepared this MANUALLY. How could I specify that in the challenge?

Comment: I believe it's customary to specify if trailing spaces / new lines are permitted and if so, how many

Comment: @AsoneTuhid for spaces I think it is ok because it does not deform the shape, but I do not think so for new lines, what do you think?

Comment: Not between the lines, of course. I mean new lines after the whole drawing. Some people put restrictions (none, one, whatever). Nice art btw

Comment: @AsoneTuhid yes of-course, thanks a lot for this remarks.

Comment: Can you write a reference implementation which beats bzip2 and gzip, preferably by a few percent?

Answer (score -3):

## Reverse Code Golf- Print out two by using variables a and b that both equal one and adding them without any extraneous lines.

Your task is very simple, display that 1+1=2, except you need as many commands and non extraneous lines as possible.

What counts as non-extraneous? If one cannot remove any kind of sequence or segment of commands, then the program is counted as non-extraneous. The variable names need to be only one byte each, without any kind of trailing zeroes or insignificant digits.

Input: nothing

Output: "2" or 2 or whatever, as long as the program runs 1+1.

Sample: Java- `System.out.println( Integer.parseInt( "1" ) + Integer.parseInt( "1"));`

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1960/ obviously inspired by this

Comment: See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9584/194

Comment: What is a "sequence"? What is a "segment"?

Comment: The only way we've found to express your "non-extraneous" criteria is [tag:pristine-programming], which is very strict but much less ambiguous.

Answer (score -3):

## Send the pairs

Write two program A and B. A takes 1024 pairs of integers `(a,b)`, where 0≤`a`<2<sup>32</sup>, 0≤`b`<1024, and all `a`s are different. Output a positive integer. B take the output of A and one `a` from the input pairs of A, and output its `b`.

Smallest output of A under a same random test data win.

Comment: To be a truly objective challenge, the test data should be included in the question; but then B could hard-code it and A could output `1` as a flag to invoke the hard-coded data.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't think hiding the test case make the challenge less objective.

Comment: @user202729, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1369/194 . If I can't tell whether a change to my answer makes it better or worse, it's not an objective challenge. If the only person who can tell is the OP, then the judging is a black box which from the outside is indistinguishable from a purely subjective judgement.

Comment: @PeterTaylor https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/308/ (+15 vote)

Comment: @l4m2, that agrees perfectly with the last sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No if the test is public some days after

Comment: @l4m2, then you would lack a winning criterion until you post those tests publicly.

Comment: @JungHwanMin A recent meta post explicitly allowed that.

Answer (score -3):

Write a program that takes a list of strings as input and creates trees of prefixes as such:

```
Hi_there_how_are_you?
Hi_there_would_you_mind?
Hi_the_weather_is_nice
Hills_are_green
Many_of_us
May_has_11_days
May_has_11_days_left
IWillLearnTheTrombone
IWillLearnTheSaxophone
IWillLearnThePiano
```

Which would output:

```
Hi Hi_there Hi_there_how_are_you?
            Hi_there_would_you_mind?
   Hi_the_weather_is_nice
   Hills_are_green
Ma Many_of_us
   May_has_11_days May_has_11_days
                   May_has_11_days_left
IWillLearnThe IWillLearnTheTrombone
              IWillLearnTheSaxophone
              IWillLearnThePiano
```

The input strings shall contain no spaces and the output shall be separated by at least one space, any number of extra line breaks or spaces are allowed. The output above is formatted to explain the challenge, the following formatting is also valid:

```
Hi Hi_there Hi_there_how_are_you? Hi_there_would_you_mind? Hi_the_weather_is_nice Hills_are_green Ma Many_of_us May_has_11_days May_has_11_days May_has_11_days_left IWillLearnThe IWillLearnTheTrombone IWillLearnTheSaxophone IWillLearnThePiano
```

This question is a kind of reverse of this [Prefix Tree Traversal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/prefix-tree-traversal). This is code golf, shortest code in bytes win.

**Note:** I'm struggling with the output? What would be the most 'fun'/ have high potential for cleverness? The one I have now just looks like a mess. Can i have output as a list of lists(of lists)? Or do that hinder people?

Comment: [Related (make an alphabeTrie)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170580/76162). Very close, though I think it might depend on your output format on whether it is a dupe

Comment: I would mark it as a duplicate to the one that Jo King linked.

Answer (score -3):

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I'm glad the sandbox exists because I have a few issues coming up with the right wording for this.

**Background**

Theoretically, any numeric pattern should exist *somewhere* in the decimal places of pi.

**Challenge**

Given any numeric input, find the index (location?) of the first occurrence of that input in the decimal place of pi

Example cases:

- 1 = 1
- 14 = 1
- 41 = 2
- 897 = 11

**Rules:**

any numeric input, can't see why it should be limited by any number of characters. 
I am not sure about limitations, but this could get computationally intense if it's a large sequence of numbers that occur very deep into pi. Do I need to add any restrictions to cater for computational complexity?

Comment: We'be had this challenge [before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161155/71256). That one only requires the first few digits, but I think we've had enough challenges about pi that this won't add anything

Comment: "_Theoretically, any numeric pattern should exist somewhere in the decimal places of pi._" - how do you know that?

Answer (score -3):

### Tags:

Code-Bowling

## Name: Two is an error, One runs fine!

The challenge is simple.

When one character is removed from the given program, it should not error, but when two are removed, it should error.

**PENALTIES:**

If you repeat one Unicode character in the program, then your score will be the number of bytes subtracted by the Unicode value of the character (0 for NUL, 10 for newline, 64 for A, etcetera).

Else, your score is the number of bytes.

As always, since this is code bowling, **most bytes win**!

Comment: What if I repeat two characters in the program?

Comment: What if I just have a really large amount of NUL bytes?

Comment: Is it ok if the program itself error/not error?

Comment: What about infinite loop?

Comment: This question needs major work: in its current state I would definitely vote to close it, and the only question would be whether to close as Too Broad or to close as Unclear. It's too broad because there's no specification for what the program must do. It's unclear because it's not specific enough on the quantifiers around the character removal: if it should be robust against the removal of *any* character, be explicit. See [tag:radiation-hardening] for existing questions in this area, both for examples of how to word them and to ensure that it's different enough to be new and interesting.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Although the program can do anything, it should not be too broad if the challenge is sufficiently hard.

Comment: About the removal of any character: I guess that the score is \$len-\sum_{c}{c\times \max(0,n(c)-1)}\$ for \$len\$ = program length in bytes and \$n(c)\$ = number of occurences of character c in program, but I'm not sure.

Comment: LENGUAGE win!!!

Answer (score -3):

Output a number \$n\$ such that:

1. \$n\text{mod}10=5\$
2. \$n^2\text{mod}10^{10000}=n\$

Shortest code win. You should be able to try it rather than purely know it work.

Sandbox mainly to check duplication

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy to just hardcode the number?

Comment: @JoKing We must have \$n^2\ge 10^{10000}\$, so \$n\ge 10^{5000}\$ which if naively hardcoded takes \$5000 \log_2{10}\$ bits.

Comment: However, we already have [modular multiplicative inverse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140357/modular-multiplicative-inverse) challenge, I expect most answers to be very similar.

Comment: @user202729 It's likely that you'll get 1 in that way or be too slow so I need time requirement

Comment: @l4m2 Most solutions there use extended Euclid algorithm so they will not be too slow...

Comment: @user202729 So they'll get 1

Comment: Get 1 what? The correct answer is 810...90625.

Comment: Will how many languages use [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EoyC/XMNUx0hLy9AACHQMDaAsTc3//wE)?

Answer (score -3):

## Integer or decimal to array and array to decimal or integer

### Task

Write two functions

1) Convert an integer or decimal to array of integers that potentially includes a single decimal

2) Convert array including integers and potentially a single decimal to integer or decimal

### Input

Integer or decimal to array

- An integer or decimal

Array to integer or decimal

- An array

### Output

Integer or decimal to array

- An array containing each digit of the input at an individual index with the first decimal portion of input containing the decimal character.

Array to integer or decimal

- An integer or decimal equal to input

## Specification

When the first digit of a decimal is a 0 , and a digit follows, that value includes all 0's up to and including the last digit of that decimal, else the decimal portion is spread or expanded to the remainder of the decimal portion for the remainder of indexes of the array, that is: `-0.01 <-> [-0.01]`, `100.01 <-> [1,0,0,0.01]`, `100.0001 <-> [1,0,0,0.0001]`

## Test cases

```
Input <----------> Output

-123               [-1,-2,-3]
4.4                [4,0.4]
44.44              [4,4,0.4,4]
-0.01              [-0.01]
123                [1,2,3]
200                [2,0,0]
2.718281828459     [2,0.7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2,8,4,5,8,9]
321.7000000001     [3,2,1,0.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
809.56             [8,0,9,0.5,6]
1.61803398874989   [1,0.6,1,8,0,3,3,9,8,8,7,4,9,8,9]
1.999              [1,0.9,9,9]
100.01             [1,0,0,0.01]
545454.45          [5,4,5,4,5,4,0.4,5]
-7                 [-7]
-83.782            [-8,-3,-0.7,-8,-2]
1.5                [1,0.5]
100.0001           [1,0,0,0.0001]
```

## Winning criteria

Least amount of total (each of function or programs 1 and 2) bytes used.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: 1) What should output be for test cases 0, 200, and 1.0015? 2) I would suggest a more descriptive title. 3) Bonuses are generally discouraged in code golf, so make sure they add something to this challenge.

Comment: The string method thing is very iffy. Won't a print function in *any* language be converting a number/list of numbers to a string?

Comment: @lirtosiast `[0]`, `[200]`, `[1,0.001,5]`. What title do you suggest? Not using string methods does add something to the challenge.

Comment: @JoKing Not sure what you mean by a print function converting a number or list to a string? If JavaScript is used it means not using `\`\``, `''`, `String`, template literal, `RegExp.prototype.match()`, etc. to create or convert the input to output or add, subtract, divide, multiply, manipulate arrays are what is meant, not `print(output)` or `console.log(output)`. A user is not obligated to try for the bonus in their answer.

Comment: @guest271314 The challenge is not clear to me: why is 200 `[200]` but 100.01 `[1,0,0,.01]`? Maybe a worked-through example in the question as well as a reference implementation would help. For a title "Modified decimal expansion of a number" is a start.

Comment: @guest271314 Some languages have builtins for the digits of an integer or float e.g. Mathematica `RealDigits[3.14159]` = `[{3,1,4,1,5,9},1]` . Do those count as string methods?

Comment: @lirtosiast `200` does not contain a decimal, `100.01` contains a decimal. The reference implementation is at the question. Created the requirement from scratch while attempting to solve another inquiry. Does Mathematica have a method to check if a value is a string, integer or decimal?

Comment: I don't see any reference implementation. It might be better if you explicitly listed the rules behind the transformation

Comment: @JoKing See "Test cases". That goes back to whether to post the question here or at Software Engineering. The question does not ask users to write an entire specification (frequently edited; maintained; an entire process in and of itself). Observing the test cases: when the first digit of a decimal is a `0` , and a digit follows, that value includes all `0`'s up to and including the last digit of that decimal, else the decimal portion is spread or expanded to the remainder of the decimal portion for the remainder of indexes of the array, that is: `[-0.01]`, `[1,0,0,0.01]`, `[1,0,0,0.0001]`.

Comment: Right, you should include those rules in the question, along with what happens when the input is an integer and/or ends in zero. I'm not sure what you'd achieve by posting on Software Engineering because I doubt any form of this question would be [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @lirtosiast Correction, `200` -> `[2,0,0]`

Comment: I think the rules are clear, even if the language is a bit hard to follow. I would recommend changing the title to something a bit more descriptive. I'd also suggest removing the bonus, otherwise you're going to get a lot of questions on what a `string method` is and whether it applies to `x` feature of whatever language.

Comment: What should `-200` return? As in, do we have to distinguish between `[-2,0,0]` and `[-2,-0,-0]`?

Comment: Requiring mixed type arrays falls foul of at least one [thing to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047/194). I think there's a good case to be made for two: [Requiring multiple types as return value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17048/194) and [Making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/194).

Comment: Also, the specification should be given as a specification, not as a set of test cases to reverse-engineer.

Comment: @JoKing What do you suggest for the title? The bonus is not required. Not sure how an individual can become confused by an option that they do not have to participate in. Meeting the requirement without using strings adds an element to the challenge, for those users interested in such challenges. Good question concerning `-200`. Using own approach `[-2,0,0]` is returned, unless there is compelling reason for `[-2,-0,-0]`, `[-2,0,0]` should suffice as the same user will need to convert that back to `-200`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Am not particularly shocked that you have found issues with the question to criticize. If you have constructive input which addresses your own concerns, kindly post the suggestions to improve the question which will overcome even your own criticisms.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The specification was spawned by own trial and error and is WIP. Even where a specification is clear there is no guarantee that all parties or stakeholders will agree with the specification, re HTML and W3C, WHATWG. If you are apt at composing specifications that all parties could not possibly disagree with any grammar, language or terms used therein, then contribute your version of the specification and will post that at the question. Again, it is the users' responsibility to convert to and from number<->array. A users' answer could redefine the specification, in a good way.

Comment: I think it's quite easy to extract the constructive criticism from my previous comments: 1. Change the I/O spec so that arrays use a consistent type. 2. Add a specification for the transformation from input to output before the test cases, which does not depend on the test cases. I will add another, which relates to [another thing to avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/194) that I hadn't noticed before: 3. Either remove the bonus or make it apply also to languages which don't have strings.

Comment: "*The specification ... is WIP.*" That's fine: that's what the sandbox is for. I'm trying to identify things which need addressing before the question leaves the sandbox. "*A users' answer could redefine the specification, in a good way*" This is completely against the ethos of this site. All users should implement the same specification, because otherwise it's not a fair contest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Bonus removed. Implement the test cases at the question. What do you mean by "Add a specification for the transformation from input to output before the test cases"? Include the code that have tried at the question?

Comment: I'm guessing he means move the specification from below the test cases to the task section and remove the `Observing the test cases` part. And perhaps make it a bit clearer, for example giving us the inputs that led to `[-0.01]`, `[1,0,0,0.01]`, `[1,0,0,0.0001]` rather than having them in isolation.

Comment: @JoKing Updated.

Comment: This needs a much better spec; as it stands, the only way to understand the challenge is to reverse engineer the test cases and, even then, it's not entirely clear.

Comment: @Shaggy What solution do you suggest for improving the specification? What specifically is not clear to you?

Comment: Specifically? *Nothing* is clear to me. Try reading through the spec yourself without the test cases and forgetting that you already know in your head how everything should work - is it clear to you? As for a solution to making it clearer: start by having a look through the specs of recent, well-received challenges and note the detail they go into about what is expected of solutions and what is & isn't allowed. Then rewrite your own spec in a similar manner so there's no (or very little) room for doubt or confusion. (1/2)

Comment: Add a worked example, if necessary - sometimes it can be tricky to put everything into words. It also helps if the worked example includes edge cases. (2/2)

Comment: @Shaggy Am able to conceptualize the expected outputs due to attempts at trying to solve [OEIS A217626](https://oeis.org/A217626) directly, see [Permutations to the nines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257). Have composed a POC in JavaScript where have found 2 bugs in own implementation; fixed 1st. Using `BigInt` may help. Can post or link to the code if that would be helpful. Consider `~~(128.625*9*1.074)//1243`
,`~~(128.625*9*1.144)//1324` what am attempting to achieve is to expand, e.g., `1.074`, `1.144` to an array for the ability to fine-tune calculations.

Comment: @Shaggy The potential edge cases are perhaps infinite. The question is difficult to describe in english words, and appears to be out of scope of Code Review SE for current code, see [Posting a question where part of the code contains a known bug](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9044/47730) and as suggested by JoKing (if their assessment is correct) out of scope for Software Engineering SE. Am not aware of any comparable published (FOSS) requirements; what you read _is_ the edge case of the question itself. Asked here as PPCG users are well-suited to solving such an inquiry.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for help fixing a bug in some "real-world" code, in which case this is indeed beyond the scope of PPCG and the other sites you mentioned; the site you're looking for is Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shaggy Am banned from StackOverflow. And in any case, would encounter the same response there as here. Posted here as estimated users being more apt at comprehending non-ordinary requirements, and accepting challenges to meet the requirement of the same. The requirement at the question is clear from perspective here. Users have commented that the requirement is not clear yet those comments are not clear themselves as users have failed to indicate precisely what is not clear to them; you first posted "it's not entirely clear." then "Nothing is clear to me." which are inconsistent statements.

Comment: @Shaggy No, not looking for a fix for the bugs encountered. Solved 1st bug, can solve other bug; or use the existing code that composed which returns expected result for each case where the fixed code caused the other bug to be viewable; that is, switch the case for those specific inputs. Am interested in how users _approach_ solving the requirement. To make the requirement even more challenging for self, imposed the restriction on self that could not use string conversion to meet requirement, which have achieved in JavaScript: removed from this question. Thus, the question is solvable.

Comment: @JoKing Cannot comment at main site due to <50 points. Do any of the answers at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175693/9erilous-9ermutations meet the requirement?

Comment: @guest271314 I mean, it's your criteria... but no, I don't think so. They all calculate the actual permutations and then the difference between them. It may have been a little premature to place the bounty before anyone had actually done it though

Comment: @JoKing Posted the bounty mainly because of your suggestion to do so with own "points" following your apparent issue with listing your question at list of open bounties. The bounty was prospective incentive to attempt to achieve the requirement. Follow through. Just wanted to make sure that you concurred that the inquiry had not been resolved, the specific requirement had not been met by answer of the answers. The rampant selective censorship at SE sites shows no sign of change. Housecleaning.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you'd deleted the bounty post. I think you misunderstood what I meant when I commented. I was just clarifying that if an answer were to be posted, the 500 rep would come from me, though you could add some rep if you wanted. There was no censorship of your post and I'm not sure why you deleted it. Typically on PPCG, we post the bounties *after* a valid answer has been posted, in order to make sure the rep doesn't go to waste, especially if the task is very hard or possibly impossible

Comment: @JoKing Yes, apparently did not gather the context of your comment. In any event, the bounty is active now, until tomorrow. Since no answer has met requirement, the most votes will get 1/2 the bounty. No way to communicate that on main site now that have 27 "points".

Comment: @JoKing FWIW Re this sandbox question [Number (integer or decimal) to array, array to number (integer or decimal) without using strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54433007/)

Comment: @Adám Re [Split and recombine a number](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17108/31257) see link at above comment.

Answer (score -3):

## Introduction

The original creator of this meme has gone blind, lost his internet and accidentally deleted all his memes. Except this one. He has this one last meme on his desktop, and since he can't see, he wants to know what this meme is.

By hearing it.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to write the shortest program that will produce a playable audio file that the meme creator will play to hear the text in this meme.

- The input is the meme below
- The output will be a audio file that reads the output text in English and has a slight pause after a colon or a new line. But don't read out 'colon'

Answer the following questions for your readers.

- You can use any programming language
- You can use any existing library
- Output audio must be playable by vlc
- Networking is not allowed, you cannot connect to any internet services
- Shortest answer wins

## Input and Output

Input:

[image: surprised pikachu eyesight]

Output:

Me: spends 8 hours per day on the internet

Eyesight: gets worse

me:

Comment: The output would always be hardcoded, so there's no point in the input

Comment: This challenge would be nice with different memes as test cases. Otherwise it would be hardcoded as said previously.

Answer (score -3):

## Compress briefly

Compress and decompress [the first chapter of *Worm*](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/1-1/), beginning with the opening words "Class ended" and ending with the closing words "my best friend." (including the period). You do not need to include any of the formatting (copy and paste as plain text).

### Rules

- You may not use any built-in or imported compression functions or procedures. You must implement the compression yourself.
- You may either write one program to compress and another to decompress, or one program that does both. If you wish, the second option can be a polyglot, where compiling as one language compresses and compiling as the other decompresses.
- Your program must be no more than 2000 bytes long. You may, at your option, compress your program with `bzip2` or `gzip` before measuring its size for the purpose of meeting this limit.
- Your program does not need to work for any other text.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- Standard I/O rules apply.

### Scoring

- The score is the sum of the total number of bytes of your program(s) and the total number of bytes in the compressed text.
- If you use a single program to compress and decompress, then you may have to pay a penalty. Specifically, you must pay a number of bytes equal to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the shell command needed to (compile and) run your compression program and the one needed to run your decompression program. You can calculate this [online](https://planetcalc.com/1721/). A special exception: if you choose to write a polyglot, then you can leave out the paths to the compilers/interpreters when you calculate the penalty.

Tags: code-challenge, compression

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately)

Comment: @Beefster, a bit, but I think there are enough differences to make competitive answers largely incompatible.

Comment: I don't think any answers are going to outperform gzip/bzip/whatever. There's no obvious patterns to exploit in the text.

Comment: Also: how is this different from [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]?

Comment: @Beefster, it's different because I don't allow the code to be big enough to have much chance of encoding the text in it. It doesn't have to outperform industrial-strength algorithms. That mention had to do with the source code size limit, intended to give extremely verbose languages the opportunity to participate.

Comment: Every answer will be some variant of `import gzip; gzip.compress(story)`

Comment: @Beefster, is my explicit prohibition of that insufficient? My first rule is that you can't use a built-in or imported compression function.

Comment: That sounds a lot more interesting than it actually is. There's a reason "do X without Y" questions have fallen out of favor. Compression challenges are hard to write. At the very least, you need some exploitable pattern common to a class of strings. This simply isn't the case in the linked text.

Comment: Even without using built-ins the best answer will use some variant of Huffman coding that fits in 2000 bytes. LZ77 is also pretty easy to implement and works well on text.

Answer (score -3):

## Output an alphabet suite

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

A successor to the [ŋarâþ crîþ alphabet challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/output-the-%c5%8bar%c3%a2%c3%be-cr%c3%ae%c3%be-alphabet-song-without-using-many-letters).

Outputting the alphabet song with as few letters as possible was too easy, but what about outputting many of them?

Your challenge is to write as many programs as you can, **with no two programs sharing any Unicode codepoints**, and each program outputting the names of the letters of the alphabet (or the glyphs of some other kind of phonetic script) used by a different language. For instance, one program can [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet)

```
a bee cee dee e eff gee aitch i jay kay el em en o pee cue ar ess tee u vee double-u ex wye zed
```

and another program can [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#Alphabet_in_Spanish)

```
a be ce de e efe ge hache i jota ka ele eme ene eñe o pe cu erre ese te u uve uve doble equis ye zeta
```

Notes:

- For a given language, there will probably be some leeway in what you can output.
- Unlike in the previous challenge, you don't need to worry about any particular punctuation. You should at least separate each letter name with whitespace.
- You must output the names of the letters, not the letters themselves (so `A B C`... is invalid), unless the letters are literally pronounced so in the language in question.
- If a language uses both capital and lowercase letters, then you may output the letter names in either case. If it uses only one of them, then you must output the alphabet in that case.
- You must use a different language's alphabet for each program, but you are allowed to use the same script in the context of different languages.
- Constructed languages are allowed, as long as they predate the challenge.
- You may use different programming languages for each program. Or the same.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

TODO:

- is the requirement against sharing any codepoints too strict?

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but suspect that the major reason that you're getting downvoted is that it's totally unclear what outputs are valid or not, and skimming the edges of that is where most of the byte savings are going to come from in a [tag:code-golf]. That said, I don't think this *is* code golf, despite having the tag. You'll probably find that, when any golfing aspect is removed, the strings to print are more or less irrelevant, so you might as well use a fixed, objective set of strings instead of the ones you have.

Answer (score -3):

## add two numbers in string representation

#### Idea:

Given two strings representing **non-negative** integers in base 10, return the string corresponding to their sum - without any explicit arithmetic operations. This means you have to implement incrementing (probably with a lookup and indexing) and carrying (probably with iteration or recursion) on your own. Comparisons and boolean operations are allowed.

#### Examples:

```
"1" + "1" = "2"
"5" + "6" = "11"
"0" + "8" = "8"
```

#### I/O:

Write a function or program which takes the two strings in a way you want to. 
Output, print or return the solution in whatever way you want.

**Ah, and also don't forget that this is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes will win. Also, all standard loophole rules and so on apply (you should know from all the other challenges!)**

---

## Sandbox

This challenge changed, evolved and got compressed during discussion with [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m) starting from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17908/74284) (feel free to review the edits and chat of this post on how we got here)

#### Tags for cgcc post:

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addition) [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

Comment: This is still "Do X without Y", and Y is not always clear-cut. What counts as an "explicit arithmetic operation" in lambda calculus?

Comment: @PeterTaylor my english is not the best in the world and also i am not a pro in thins like loopholes or coding terminus around maths. you have any idea how to propose this or what kind of operations to prohibit? I would just come up with explicite "+" "-" "*" and "/" operations directly on the string representations (also to exklude languages which can handle interpreting strings as numbers). But are there furter operations I forget?

Comment: I don't think it can be fixed.

Comment: I agree this can't be defined objectively. The only way I can see this working is if the output was required to include the steps of calculation so that it's no longer an non-observable requirement. That would probably involve specifying a particular approach to implement though. I can't guess whether such a restriction would make the challenge interesting, but I suspect it would not.

Comment: Guess then I will better not post this question outside of the sandbox.. But thanks to you all so far! :)

Answer (score -3):

The goal is to make a program that is compilable in as many languages as possible.

- The program must be compilable with a specific compiler version and compiler parameters without any errors.
- The program may result in an error when run.
- The source code must not be empty or whitespace.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot) is somewhat similar in spirit but not the same. This probably is a duplicate of *something*, strictly or less so, but that's the first thing that came to mind

Comment: A null program is compilable in most(if not all) languages. (Including specific compilers of C(in IOCCC).)

Comment: @A_ I've added an additional rule.

Comment: As-is, this will be closed as *Too Broad*, since there's no "thing" for the program to do. Have a look at the [tag:polyglot] tag and see what others have done.

Comment: Define "compile".

Answer (score -3):

**Writing a WebCrawler**

**Challenge**

Design a web crawler that recursively extracts all the hyperlinks from the HTML of the web page and does the same for every hyperlinked page it finds. The webcrawler must store the hyperlinks in a separate file

**How The WebCrawler Works**

First the webcrawler should download the HTML file of the URL the user inputted.

Second the webcrawler will copy every single hyperlink embedded in the hyperlink and paste it into an output text file. The best general way to do this based on my experience is to have the webcrawler iteratively search through the HTML file for an "a href" tag. Be careful about what kind of hyperlinks are embedded in those tags. Sometimes only the subdomain directories of a complete hyperlink are embedded in this

For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota may simply have an a href tag in the HTML file of a webpage as: "/wiki/Toyota"

After extracting all the hyperlinks of the first webpage, visit all the hyperlinks found on the base webpage starting from the the first hyperlink found and repeat all the steps above. The only exception to doing this is obviously if the hyperlink fails to lead to an HTML page.

**Input**

The program must accept only one URL as input.

**Output**

A text file that lists every hyperlink that it finds.
Note:

Your webcrawler must avoid revisiting webpages it has already crawled. This can cause the crawler get trapped in a "circular link loop" where it continously visits the same pages endlessly.

**Note:**

Special consideration will be given to submissions that prove they are capable of crawling deep web websites, including those with the .onion sites.

Answer (score -3):

## Create a "Transpiler"

for the purpose of this challenge, a transpiler is any program that takes valid source code from one language as input and produces a program valid in another language that performs the same actions. Calling the original languages interpreter is not banned.

Posts should start with "SRCLANG to DSTLANG in LANG; X bytes" as a heading.

Here's an example post:

## Shell to Ruby in Ruby; 41 bytes

```ruby
puts'`bash #{Data}`
__END__
'+STDIN.read
```

Here we use the somewhat obscure `Data` constant to embed arbitrary data in the program. this has the advantage of never having to escape anything.

Each "triple" of source, destination, and working language represents its own category, as this challenge varies greatly in difficulty depending on the languages used.

Comment: What is the winning criterion? Are there requirements for the languages used?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms lowest byte count, as usual. I guess no strict subsets as well, so you can't say `cat` is a `sh` to `bash` transpiler

Comment: How would this be consistently graded? I don't get how this is fair to all answers.

Comment: Is `g++` a C++ to x86 assembly transpiler? "this challenge varies greatly in difficulty depending on the languages used" I'd say it varies in difficulty way too much.

Comment: @thedefault. Yes, but it's far from trivial. As for variation, like I said, each "triple" of languages forms it's own category. If it's necessary to have 1 winner, I guess it could be `popularity-contest`.

Answer (score -3):

### I have the following code. Help me make it code shorter.

```
new Promise(r=>r(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<h1>Example</h1>'],{type:'text/html'})))).then(u=>open(u)&&setTimeout(t=>URL.revokeObjectURL(u),2e3))
```

#### The Catch:

- This has to be in JavaScript
- It cannot contain semicolons
- It must be a "one-liner"
- It must have the same steps as the code above:

  1. Create a blob URL from a blob
  2. Open a browser window of the blob URL
  3. Revoke the blob URL

#### Extras

- The winner will be decided by the shortest amount of bytes
- If you try this in another language, you will still get an upvote

Answer (score -3):

[pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi) [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output)

## Most digits of Pi in a hundred bytes

Comment: It's likely possible to output infinitely many.

Comment: @thedefault. how?

Comment: By using one of the many known formulas for pi. And if you do not use a formula for pi, you're compressing random digits (it's possible to store around 240 digits like this). https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47808 has multiple answers below 100 bytes.

Answer (score -3):

## Reinvent math

The task is simple. Define the basic operators (+, -, *, /) without using them directly.

Also banned:

- any add-assign (`+=`) and its equivalents
- basically anything *intended* to be used as a basic arithmetic operation

Program should consist of at least 4 binary functions, one for each operation. they may call other functions defined in your program, including each other. The types of the arguments to the function may be any types that the basic arithmetic operators work on, except for types that are less than 3 bits in size.

Shortest code wins

Comment: Thank you for using the sandbox. Have you considered stating the required argument domain? And how should one answer? Using for functions/programs with the total length being the score? Can the four share code?

Comment: Also, what does "using them directly" mean? Does that mean we can't use those four symbols or their equivalents in whatever language we use? And do we implement them for integers or floating-point numbers?

Comment: If our language allows e.g. using `_plus_` instead of `+`, is that allowed?

Comment: @user I feel like it it's fairly clear what "using them directly" means. I can't really think of an alternative interpretation. Any numeric type which the basic operators work on will do. For most c-derived languages, this will be floats and ints.

Comment: @binarycat It's not clear to me - I can't tell if you're talking about those four specific symbols or the equivalent operators in the answer's language (if there is an equivalent operator). Also, could you add to the draft that any numeric type will do?

Comment: Are we allowed to use the basic operators in *each others'* definitions, e.g. `plus(x,y)=x--y`?

Comment: @Adám Ideally, the operator will behave the same as the builtin, but if that's not possible due to restrictions in the language, that's ok. Also, no `_plus_` wouln't be allowed. That is still using the basic operator of addition.

Comment: @binarycat OK, that's useful information (i.e. it should be included in the challenge specification).

Comment: Are we allowed to use the corresponding operations *in a different language*  than the one we're answering in, i.e. to call out?

Comment: [Pro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brestricted-source%5D+user%3A43319+is%3Aq)-tip: I note that you have never posted any challenges. [tag:restricted-source] challenges are notoriously difficult to get right. I'm not saying this is a bad challenge, not at all, but I highly recommend posting a few well-received standard [tag:code-golf] challenges before attempting a [tag:restricted-source] one.

Comment: @Adám the post has been updated to reflect the fact that the answer is no

Comment: @Adám It's really not restricted source, just the "no using a builtin that does exactly what the challange says" loophole.

Comment: This is a textbook example of a "do X without Y" challenge and simply isn't considered interesting on this site.

Comment: @Beefster no it isn't, it's "do X without X", and who put you in charge of what's interesting?

Comment: @binarycat You seem very convinced that this isn't [do-X-without-Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/43319). I'd be very interested in hearing why you think so, especially considering that your text literally says "Define [=do] the basic operators (+, -, *, /) [=X] **without** using them directly [=Y]."

Comment: @Beefster "simply isn't considered interesting on this site" [citation needed]

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Add without addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20996/78410), as the same techniques can be used to define all four operators.

Answer (score -3):

## Google search

Challenge is very simple, you have to get a string as input and then launch the default web browser, and search for that string in Google.

Input string will have only characters `a-zA-Z`

Google search URL is `google.com/search?q=querystring`

Standard loopholes apply, Internet connection allowed, but only to `google.com` domain

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

---

Author note: challenge title sucks, please improve it!

Comment: I suspect on many (older) systems the notion of a default browser does not exist. In addition, I think there are many other escape characters. Of course, you could allow the answers to fail - but without the encoding requirements this is probably a dupe of some old basic internet challenge.

Comment: Also, `%20` is not the right escape sequence for a `+`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The first one is not really an issue, if the programming language doesn't have the thing then it can't have an answer.

Comment: For the challenge: it's best to specify which characters might appear in the input.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman,user202729 edited, now input will only have `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Most languages can't launch a browser. Also, there are dozens like this already,

Comment: Sorry, I missed your edit earlier. I think if you want to go ahead with this you need to define what the "default browser" is, and what to do if it isn't present. Depending on how you define it, this may not be a dupe, but I imagine you will have some trouble with different systems defining it differently.

Answer (score -3):

## Enumerate all possible IPv4 addresses

Title might make the challenge hard, but it's easy.

You have to print all the possible IPv4 addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Standard loopholes apply, no internet usage for this

Tags: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity),[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: Definitely a dupe of the [ipv6 one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59934/31625).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It just happens to be easy to duplicate-search for because they're both IP addresses. In terms of similarity, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times is very close to both.

Answer (score -3):

## Reverse error quine

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf),[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/print-your-code-backwards-reverse-quine)

Write a quine that prints it own source code in reverse, but to STDERR.

**Penalties**

- +200 using other files I.E. `reverse.txt`
- +150 internet usage
- +100 reading own source code

**Rules**

- Minimum length of source is 2 bytes
- Standard loopholes apply

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins

Comment: As a reverse error quine, it will probably just be basically the same as a plain error quine, but with the creative solutions using syntax errors not valid. The things with penalties should probablly just be disallowed or someone will just do sh, 6 bytes + 20 penalty, `tac $0`. You can also add `[tag:quine]`

Comment: But thanks for using the sandbox!

Comment: Why the rule `No palindromes`? Aside from Stack Cats, there are pretty much no languages that print a palindromic error.

Comment: Changed the rules: 1) Increased penalty (None will not now dare to read own source code) 2) Palindromes allowed 3) Added the tag [tag:quine]

Comment: Penalty in code golf is discouraged by itself, just like [bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/78410). Accessing the internet/other files/the source file itself to get the desired output is already considered a standard loophole, so you should just say they're not allowed, and remove the penalties altogether.

Comment: Also, another thing to avoid: [using old challenges as a model](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10223/78410).

Answer (score -3):

## “Simple” Programming Homework

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

---

Your friend has been caught sleeping in class again! As punishment, his computer science teacher has assigned him homework, knowing that he will not be able to solve it due to not having paid any attention.

The assignment seems deceiving simple at first; all that is required is to output the string:

```
John Doe
```

Unfortunately, the teacher is intent on making the simple assignment much more difficult. Since your friend was not listening when the teacher explained the concept of strings and numbers, the teacher forbids him from using any number character (0-9) or the quotes (`"`, `'`, `` ` ``).

Can you help your friend solve this problem with the shortest code possible, and save his computer science grade in the process?

Try to find the shortest code in each language!

<sub>Note: it is encouraged to try to solve this problem in languages where string/character literals exist but cannot be used due to the restrictions (most mainstream languages are like this, e.g. C++).</sub>

Comment: Better leaving it here for a while (and ask in chat often) to see if people mostly agree that what "literal" means is obvious. (see, bash have `echo John Doe` and BF has `+++something+++.`, and most languages doesn't have a formal specification to define English names for the components of the language)

Comment: Other than that (huge) point it is clear enough. [*please review other sandbox posts*]

Comment: @user202729 Ask which chat?

Comment: @user202729 I thought this would be interesting for most languages that do use quotes for string and character literals like C, but I do see how it might be too easy in some languages.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte

Answer (score -3):

## Geometry Dash Clone in a weird Way?

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [cloning-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning-games)

Try to make a functional clone of Geometry Dash in the shortest time.

### How GD Works.

- You have a cube. In the clone, it can be as small as you want, but no bigger than 2x2.
- You have to jump over spikes. The key to do this is (preferably) the up arrow key, but can be any option you want (simply tell me in your answer what key is it.
- If you touch the spikes, the screen says "Game Over." and exits in 3 seconds.
- There are blocks! You can jump on them, but touching them from the left side results in the same thing that happens if you touch the spikes.
- A song plays in the background. How you do this is up to you.

### Rules:

1. 3 Extra points for working forwards and backwards.
2. Must have the letter `a` 5-7 times and no `q` at all!
3. Allows ascii art type output and text input (standard input)!

### Sandbox Questions

How is this even going to work?

Comment: Welcome to codegolf! I don’t really recommand to compare how fast submit time after question release, since there maybe someone out there already holding an answer, and it also really timezone dependent.

Comment: But it could be one of the [tag:code-golf] problem, and allowing ascii art type output and text input (standard input) could allow more language to compete.

Comment: also the flawless limit is kinda weird, extra point for certain language is not suggested, if you still want to give extra point, you may want to say how much extra point is.

Answer (score -3):

## Get Floor of N ^ (3 / 2)

Your task is very simple:

Get The Floor of N ^ (3 / 2)

[OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C8%2C11%2C14%2C18%2C22&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

This is Code Golf so the winner wins

### Test Cases

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 5
4 => 8
5 => 11
10 => 31
13 => 46
27 => 140
33 => 189
49 => 343
68 => 560
89 => 839
98 => 970
100 => 1000
136 => 1586
256 => 4096
500 => 11180
147385 => 56582212
```

## Meta

- Any feedback?

Answer (score -3):

## Who Loses The number guessing game?

You are playing a number guessing game. You know everyone's guesses, and who won, and want to figure out who was in last place.

### Task

Your task is to take a dictionary of guesses as input, along with the name of the winner. You should then return the name of the player whose guess was the farthest from the winner's, or if there are multiple, the lowest.

A input:

```
[{"Joe": 800, "Mama": 1000, "Biden": 1200}, "Joe"]
```

Means that the aproxximate score winner is Joe, The next is Mama, Mama is greater than Joe and Mama is greater than Biden.

So the loser is Biden.

All guesses are guaranteed to be unique

### Test cases

```
[{"A": 100, "B": 200, "C": 300}, "A"] => "C"
[{"Hello": 200, "World": 201}, "World"] => "Hello"
[{"Blah": 210, "Bruh": 984, "Boo": 314}, "Boo"] => "Bruh"
[{"A": 6, "B": 7, "C": 666, "D": 1000}, "C"] => "A"
[{"AC": 100, "BE": 200, "CE": 300}, "B"] => "CE"
```

## Meta

- Any feedback?
- Dupe?

Comment: What's the point of having this weird input format? Why not just take and return indices?

Answer (score -3):

## Convert decimal to unary in fewest regex codes [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)

Your task is to Convert decimal to undary in fewest regex codes

Every regex code is substitution mode.

The regex code counts the regex code, without test string and Substitution code

A example

```
^2, |11
^3, |111
^4, |1111
...
\|, <empty>
```

This scores infinity, But don't try this.

### Rules

- Your score is always non-infinity
- Any flavor is allowed.
- Your score is the number of regex codes
- every length of regex code is non-infinite

## Meta

- Any feedback?

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what exactly a "regex code" is?

Answer (score -3):

## Nth Eights Challenge

### Inputs:

There are 2 inputs: The amount of eights to be used in the calculation, and the number to solve for.

### What to solve:

The program needs to insert operators in between each eight, so when the newly created equation is calculated, the answer is the number that was trying to be solved for. When the equation is calculated, there is no operator priority.

### Rules:

The only operators allowed are:

```
+
-
*
/
(And parentheses)
```

You may insert multiple operators between each number. No extra numbers are allowed.
There must be an operator inserted in between each 8.
The answer must be displayed when the program finishes.

### Examples:

```
#User inputs
Amount of eights: 4
Solve for: 15

#Answer
8+8-8/8
```

```
#User inputs
Amount of eights: 4
Solve for: 10

#Answer
(8+8)/8+8
```

### Winning Criteria:

The winning criteria is for the program written in the least amount of characters.

Comment: 0. What is [winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria) for this question? Code-golf or fastest code? 1. What operators are allowed? May I insert multiple operators between two 8s or may concatenation two 8s without any operator? 2. Is operator priority considered? 3. How fast should it be? Define by time usage on specified (batch of) testcases? Or defined by algorithm time complexity? 4. Language specified challenges are generally unwelcome on this site.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241404/92901), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164876/92901).

Comment: Do you mean "characters" or "bytes"?

Answer (score -3):

## Get the Nth line

### Challenge

Let's have a file `f` and a number `n`. Your task is to get the nth line from the file.

### Constrains

- file `f` exists and has at least `n` lines
- you can index lines from 0 or 1, whichever you prefer

### Example

- input: `n` = 2 (indexing from 1) and content of file `f` is:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

- output: `bar`

### Rules

- this is `code-golf` challenge, so the shortest code wins
- [standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use stdin/stdout, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs
- [default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: I thought the entire point of this sandbox was to get feedback. Down-votes without any comment is the complete opposite.

Comment: I think the downvotes here are just because it's not a very interesting challenge. There are no comments because there's nothing actually *wrong* with your post, so no feedback to really give, but people just don't think it's interesting for [tag:code-golf]. You could post it and I don't think it would get closed or anything, but it wouldn't get many upvotes. Thank you for using the sandbox nonetheless.

Answer (score -3):

## Knight mover

Your task is to move a chess knight between the points `B` and `E`.

A chess knight moves in an L shaped pattern, like so:

```
.X.X.
X...X
..B..
X...X
.X.X.
```

The `X`s mark where the knight in position `B` can move.

There may be other chess pieces on the board, blocking the knight's movement, but for clarity, you will only be notified of where you cannot go by `#` characters. You cannot land on these marked spaces, but you can go over them. You also cannot go outside of the board.

Your goal is to find how many turns `N` are needed to go from `B` to `E`, or return `-1` if it can't be done.

### Input & Output

- You are given 2 integers `W` and `H` giving the width and height of the board
- For the next `H` lines, you are given a row of the board, containing the characters `B`, `E`, `.` and `#`
- You are allowed to take in the input as a `WxH` board as a list of strings or a character matrix

### Test case

```
3 2
..E
B..
->
1


5 5
B...E
..#..
.....
.....
.....
->
4


7 5
B..###.
####.##
...###E
..#.#.#
.#..#..
->
4


8 8
....#...
....##..
..E..#..
#...##..
.###....
........
........
.....B..
->
6
```

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Credits to [this puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/chess-cavalry)

Answer (score -3):

## Game of GO

Go is an abstract strategy board game for two players, in which the aim is to surround more territory than the opponent.

Given a board (where some stones are already added) and a list of moves to be executed next, check whether the moves are valid and (if they are valid) execute them.

After executing all moves in the list the expected output is either not valid if at least one of the moves is invalid, or the new state of the board after all moves were executed.

Rules of Go:

- Two players place stones of their color (by turns)
- If a stone is completely surrounded by stones of the other player (or by the edge of the field) this stone is beaten and is removed from the board
- If stones of the same color are placed next to each other they build a group
- If the group is completely surrounded by stones of the other player (or by the edge of the fields) this group is beaten and all of its stones are removed from the board
- A stone can be placed on every free field on the board except for:

> A position in which it would be completely surrounded by the stones of the other player (no suicidal moves allowed). Except this move beats some other stones which leads to it not being surrounded anymore

> A position that would create the same board that was there before the other player made his move (to prevent an infinite loop of killing stones) which is named KO-rule (see a test case for an example)

- Points (which are not important for this puzzle) are made by empty fields that are surrounded by the stones of a player or by enemy stones that are beaten

For a more detailed description please visit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)#Rules)

### Input & Output

- You are first given an integer `S` for the size of the field (the field is a square of `S×S`)
- You are then given an integer `M` for the number of moves that are to be made on the board
- You are then given a line of the board where `.` is an empty field, `B` is a field with a black stone and `W` is a field with a white stone on it (each line contains `S` characters) for the next `S` lines
- You are then given a move that is described by the player color, and the position (separated by a space character)
- Output the expected output, else output any character you want
- You are allowed to output the board as a matrix/list
- You may assume the initial board state in the input is always valid
- You are allowed to take in the input as a list/array of lines and moves

### Testcases

```
5
5
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
B 2 2
W 2 3
B 3 2
W 3 4
B 4 3
->
.....
.....
..BW.
..B.W
...B.


5
7
BB...
B....
.....
...W.
.....
B 3 2
W 0 2
B 3 4
W 2 0
B 2 3
W 1 1
B 4 3
->
..W..
.W...
W..B.
..B.B
...B.


5
1
.....
.....
..B..
.....
.....
B 2 2
->
0


5
5
.BW..
BW...
.W...
.....
.....
B 3 4
W 4 4
B 3 3
W 2 0
B 0 0
->
0


5
3
..B..
.B.B.
.WBW.
.BW..
.....
B 3 3
W 1 2
B 2 2
->
0


5
7
.B...
BW...
WB..W
...W.
...BW
B 3 4
W 0 2
B 0 3
W 0 0
B 1 2
W 0 1
B 1 0
->
...B.
B.B..
WB..W
...WB
...B.
```

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Credits to [this puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/a-game-of-go)

Answer (score -3):

## Beaker drawing

Your task is to output the following beaker with the volume `n`:

```
_
 %      %
%       %
%       %
%       %
%       %
%%%%%%%%%
```

You are the fill `n` spaces of the beaker above, so `n=5` looks like this

```
_
 %      %
%       %
%       %
%       %
%-----  %
%%%%%%%%%
```

Even though this defies the law of physics, you are to output the beaker with the liquid of `n` volume. The volume of the beaker is `35`. The first 4 layers have a volume of 7 and the top has a layer of 6, and the `_` represents an additional volume of `1` if the beaker overspills.

### Test cases

```
34
->
_
 %------%
%-------%
%-------%
%-------%
%-------%
%%%%%%%%%

35
->
-
 %------%
%-------%
%-------%
%-------%
%-------%
%%%%%%%%%
(Note the `_` becomes a `-`)

15
->
_
 %      %
%       %
%-      %
%-------%
%-------%
%%%%%%%%%
```

You may assume `n` is positive (can be 0)

You may assume the beaker can overspill

You may perform the "flood fill" from left to right bottom to top or right to left bottom to top.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Answer (score -3):

## Play an audio file [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [audio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)

---

## Challenge

Your challenge is simple: play an audio file at a given path. Your program will take the file path as input and will play it once and quit.

To make this harder, however, you are not allowed to use external libraries, but modules that are part of your language's standard library (such as `ctypes` below) are allowed.

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- You may assume (a) specific operating system(s) and/or (a) specific file format(s).
- You may assume an absolute path.
- You do not have to hear the sound every time; you are not expected to unmute muted speakers, and you can play through whichever audio device is the most convenient. However, it must be possible to hear it every time you run it with certain settings. A window such as `Control Panel -> Sound -> Playback` on Windows must *always* be able to "show" the sound being played under at least one audio device. You are allowed to play the file under a different device each run.
- Your program must be able to play *at least* one of the audio file formats listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format#List_of_formats). Other formats are allowed, as long as one of the formats listed there is supported.
- Outputting any content to any stream, file, etc. is allowed, but the sound must be played.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where it would be trivial to do this, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

## Reference implementaion (ungolfed, Python 3, Windows only, `.wav` only)

```py
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-

from ctypes import windll

winmm = windll.winmm
audio_file = input('Audio file path: ').encode('utf_8')

winmm.PlaySound(audio_file, 0, 131072)
```

## Golfed reference implementation

```py
import ctypes;ctypes.windll.winmm.PlaySoundW(input(),0,131072)
```

Comment: "To make this harder, however, you are not allowed to use external libraries."...and then you use a library in the reference implementation?

Comment: Does "external libraries" mean libraries not coming with the standard library of the language of choice, or all libraries for that language?

Comment: I said *external* libraries, not libraries in general. `ctypes` is built-in, so it's not an external library.

Comment: @Makonede But `winmm` is not built-in.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It is in Windows.

Comment: @Makonede “External libraries” is unclear, then. External to _what_? Can I make raw calls to the hardware interface, and say that those particular drivers are part of my operating system and so not external? etc, etc.. We already have rules and conventions about all of this; trying to forbid “external libraries” won't make it more fun.

Answer (score -3):

## Visualize tag progress

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Task is pretty simple. Given non-negative positive integers `0 ≤ s ≤ 1000` and `0 ≤ a ≤ 200`, your code should draw following progress bars.

### Examples

When `s ≤ 100 or a ≤ 20`:

```
Input:15 12
Output: 
15/100 score
++++++------------------------------------
12/20 answers
+++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------

Input:3 1
Output: 
3/100 score
+-----------------------------------------
1/20 answers
------------------------------------------
  
Input:85 35
Output: 
85/100 score
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------
35/20 answers
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

When `(s > 100 and a > 20) and (s ≤ 400 or a ≤ 80)`:

```
Input:156 43
Output: 
156/400 score
++++++++++++++++--------------------------
43/80 answers
++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
  
Input:666 66
Output: 
666/400 score
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
66/80 answers
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------
```

When  `(s > 400 and a > 80) and (s ≤ 1000 and a ≤ 200)`:

```
Input:999 85
Output: 
999/1000 score
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-
85/200 answers
+++++++++++++++++-------------------------

Input:666 194
Output: 
666/1000 score
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------
194/200 answers
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--
```

The number of `+`'s in each bar is equal to the value of `a` or `s` divided by its max value (max values for `s` are `100`, `400`, `1000` and for `a` are `20`, `80`, `100`, the choice of max values ​​depends on the ranges in which the values ​​of `a` and `s` fall.), multiplied by 42 and rounded down. *This number cannot be more than 42.*  
 The number of `-`'s is equal to 42 minus the number of `+`'s.

End etc. Trailing spaces are allowed. Additional newlines are not allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

### Meta

I realized that I myself got confused in my task :) ... so this task will be in completion until this text is deleted.

Comment: "progress bars are built according to the same rules" - what are those rules? Please describe them, so that we don't need to infer them from examples.

Comment: Why should we have to "output nothing" when s>1000 and a>100? The challenge would, in my opinion, be much better if we were allowed to assume that s<=1000 and a<=100.

Comment: Please, describe the rules governing drawing the bars. Also, "`s = 666` and `a = 66`" appears twice with two different outputs.

Answer (score -3):

Your task is to create an approximation for sin(x) in the fewest characters possible.

- Given the approximation s(x), it must satisfy 0.95 * sin(x) <= s(x) <= 1.05 * sin(x)

The entry with the fewest characters wins.

Comment: Most languages already have a built-in for the sine function, so I think this would not be an interesting challenge at all. Also, FYI, [tag:code-golf] challenges (if that is what you are going for) usually score submissions by byte count, not character count.

Answer (score -3):

## Longest Possible Pythagorean Triple Triangle

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

A Pythagorean triple is a set of 3 integers \$\{a, b, c\}\$ where \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$. Your task is to, given an integer \$n\$ where \$3 ≤ n ≤ 15\$, output a Pythagorean triple using these rules:

- If \$n\$ is odd, output \$\{n, \frac{n^2-1}{2}, \frac{n^2+1}{2}\}\$.
- If \$n\$ is even, output \$\{n, \frac{n^2}{4}-1, \frac{n^2}{4}+1\}\$.

With these rules, the difference between the lengths of the longest leg and the hypotenuse is minimized.

### Rules

- Input and output can be in [any convenient format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447).
- The output does not have to be in any particular order.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Input | Output
------+-------
3     | 3 4 5
4     | 4 3 5
5     | 5 12 13
6     | 6 8 10
7     | 7 24 25
8     | 8 15 17
9     | 9 40 41
10    | 10 24 26
11    | 11 60 61
12    | 12 35 37
13    | 13 84 85
14    | 14 48 50
15    | 15 112 113
```

See [A055523](https://oeis.org/A055523) and [A055524](https://oeis.org/A055524).

Answer (score -3):

## [Repeat Hello World according to another string's length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250516/repeat-hello-world-according-to-another-strings-length)

Comment: I think arbitrarily overriding the scoring defaults is not very well received...

Comment: Which part? The "This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins!"? I've seen it in many questions, so I thought I would have to add it here. Is there a problem with it, or were you talking about something else in the question?

Comment: "Please write how many bytes it is ***in UTF-8***". A lot of languages have ther own scoring systems

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to remove the UTF-8 option?

Comment: Alright then. I've added it.

Answer (score -3):

## Do you trust this site?

*title is a work in progress*

This challenge is simple. Your program must take a URL (which will always exist) as input, download the file, and execute its contents as a program in the language your answer is in. The file will always be a valid program in your language.

### Example

```
Language: Python
Input: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GingerIndustries/d6f25007b45071e901b2b9057388d8f8/raw/25f838879fdc93f07394afc080eeef0993f55cbe/helloworld.py
Result: Program should print "Hello World!"
```

Comment: It'd probably benefit from more test cases; and how is it guaranteed that the webpage is a file?

Comment: @py3programmer All webpages are files.

Comment: As in, the URLs will have an extension in the end?

Answer (score -3):

This is a famous mathematical problem, Named as Bridges of Königsberg

**Task**

The bridges of Königsberg is a problem in mathematics which states that the path required for crossing each bridge exactly once without using a boat

[image: Bridges of https://cdn.britannica.com/77/74877-050-F5DD4C34/Leonhard-Euler-route-each-question-bridges-Swiss.jpg]

You have to find out if there is any path which uses each bridges exactly once without using a boat, if the time exceeds 36000 seconds or 10 hours the program should print no path found yet

**Rules**

Standard rules of `fastest-code`

Expected Output: Paths possible: [7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4], [2, 1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5], etc.

This is `fastest-code` so the answer with shortest time is accepted, Even if the code will take a  many days without a Quantum Computer

Comment: I'm really confused by the "programing languages starting from b" rule. What does it even mean? And what a extremely arbitrary restriction

Comment: Thanks, @mousetail I mean unofficial languages which is not included in the Wikipedia Article

Comment: What does it mean for a language to be unofficial? See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/91213 our guidelines for arbitrary restricting languages.

Comment: Thanks @mousetail, For the guidelines link

Comment: This question isn't very specific. What exactly are we supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks, @Ginger, You have to find out if there is any path which uses each bridges exactly once without using a boat, if the time exceeds 36000 seconds or 10 hours the program should print no path found yet

Comment: What is input and what is output? Without input, how can you prevent someone write a program which simply `print "[7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4]"`?

Answer (score -3):

Take one of two distinct, consistent values of your choice. For one input, check if the input is prime. For another input, check if the input is a square.

Standard loophole apply except [input complete or partial functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/76323), which is replaced with

> No input results in an infinite loop.

Comment: This challenge is pretty easy to solve in most languages, many have builtins for both parts

Comment: Why it get -3 vote and don't turn grey?

Comment: ok b/c grey is loaded earlier, and it later get vote

Answer (score -3):

## Munge my Text [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

*Inspired by [this example in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=munge#text-munging).*

Write a program that takes as input a string of arbitrary length and returns a version of that string with every letter, except the first and last, of every word randomly shuffled. "Word" is defined here as a contiguous set of alphabetical characters separated by one or more spaces or punctuation marks (`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``).

### Examples

```
Input: Professor Abdolmalek, please report your absences promptly.
Possible output: Poefsrosr Aealmlobdk, pslaee reorpt your abnseces plmrptoy.

META TODO: Add more examples
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

Comment: [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/cambridge-transposition)

Answer (score -3):

Fibonacci before the zero - Dublicate of [Negative Fibonacci Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105183/negative-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: [very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105183/negative-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: I would consider this a duplicate of the challenge @mathcat linked to. Although your version just says to output 50, this is basically just overwriting the default [tag:sequence] rules

Answer (score -3):

## See Those Sorts

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Using shapes or Unicode, show how some array of numbers is sorted with a particular sorting method. You should include selection sort, merge sort, bubble sort, quick sort, bogo sort, and at least one other sort you find interesting (maybe try one of [these](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/)).

Make sure that the speed of the sort corresponds to the actual performance on your computer. You can try adding a constant multiplier to the speed if you want.

<sup>Someone watched sort videos :)</sup>

Comment: Please note that [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest) challenges are not so well received any more. Read more [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8134/114446)

Answer (score -3):

## \$n\$ bottles of beer!

You want to recreate the song "99 Bottles of Beer", but you don't have 99 bottles!

---

Given an input non-negative integer \$n\$, output the lyrics to the song "99 Bottles of Beer" but starting from \$n\$ instead. For a few examples:

```
Input: 10

Output: 

10 bottles of beer on the wall,
10 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
9 bottles of beer on the wall.

9 bottles of beer on the wall,
9 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
8 bottles of beer on the wall.

8 bottles of beer on the wall,
8 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
7 bottles of beer on the wall.

7 bottles of beer on the wall,
7 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
6 bottles of beer on the wall.

6 bottles of beer on the wall,
6 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
5 bottles of beer on the wall.

5 bottles of beer on the wall,
5 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
4 bottles of beer on the wall.

4 bottles of beer on the wall,
4 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall,
3 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall,
2 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall,
1 bottle of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
0 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

```
Input: 1

Output:

1 bottle of beer on the wall,
1 bottle of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
0 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

### Meta:

- Any more tags?
- Is this a duplicate?
- Is the song formatted correctly in the example?
- Any more test cases?

Comment: I think the “{n} bottles of beer on the wall. {n} bottles of beer.” should be “{n} bottles of beer on the wall, {n} bottles of beer.” with a comma. At the end of the song, it’s supposed to go “1 bottle of beer on the wall, one bottle of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, {n} bottles of beer on the wall.” Also, what is the expected output for n=1 ?

Comment: @noodleman fixed. In the original version, I don't think you go to the store for more.

Comment: [Wikipedia cites several variations of the final lyric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_Bottles_of_Beer#Lyrics), but that’s how I’ve always sung it. Consider choosing one of those variations. (p.s. this challenge pretty trivial and is likely to be marked as a dupe of the regular 99 bottles of beer question, though I’m not one of the downvoters)

Answer (score -3):

## Square decomposition

Inspired by silly ideas for answers to [this CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64270042#64270042).

---

<s>Given a perfect square, take the square root of it.</s> ***NO NO NO NOT THAT CHALLENGE***

---

### Explanation

Given a square in Unicode art, output the characters that compose the square.

Rows are separated by newlines, so they cannot appear in the square. Therefore, contrary to I/O defaults, **you cannot output leading or trailing whitespace *unless* it is in the square**. You may also output in any order. Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

### Test cases

| Input | Unordered Output |
| --- | --- |
| ``` aaa aaa aaa ``` | `a` |
| ``` 1234 4567 7890 0123 ``` | `1234567890` |
| ``` " ``` | `"` |
|  |  |
|  |  |

---

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)

---

---

### Meta

- Is this a duplicate?
- Is this clear enough?
- Should I add more test cases?
- Should I add or remove any tags?
- Anything else?

Comment: So it's just printing the unique characters in a string?

Comment: @mousetail No, you must not print newlines. It is printing the unique elements that make up the square.

Comment: Yea so extremely trivial and not related to the title at all. Try to title your challenges what they actually are

Comment: @mousetail Square decomposition is not finding what makes a square!?!

Comment: Not at all, it's just removing duplicate items from a string

Comment: @mousetail which happen to be part of the square. Also, newlines may be part of the string, but you may not print them.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference for the challenge

Comment: while it is a funny idea and i do appreciate the title, it is a bit too trivial to have as a challenge, as currently posed. I think this could be improved if you actually had to find the exact string that was made to wrap to a square, like for example, `abcb` made into a 5x5 square becomes `abcba\nbcbab\ncbabc\nbabcb\nabcba`, and you have to somehow reverse that, maybe find the minimal string which could be turned into a square like that. Still might be seen as trivial to some but idk thats my suggestion :o

Comment: @thejonymyster that would be a separate challenge.

Answer (score -3):

## Generic pop-con

This is a pop-con. The objective validity criterion is that all answers are valid. Answer with most upvotes after a week will win!

Answer (score -4):

## Output the number of lines of your code

Your task is to write a program that counts the number of its lines of code and outputs them.

**Specs:**

- The number mustn't be hardcoded into the program, nor in any other external resource;
- Internet access is forbidden;
- Your program's output must be the number of lines **only**;
- Your program should not use any tool, macro, function, or similar device designed with the specific purpose of counting lines.

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

Comment: I don't see much of a challenge here. `wc -l $0`?

Comment: It can be a nice question, but needs some work. Just add something like "it should not use any tool, macro, function, or similar device designed with the specific purpose of counting lines".

Comment: @Victor Nice point, added. Thank you :)

Comment: As long as you can read the program file, it's no challenge. E.g. `print len(l for l in sys.argv[0])`. But if you forbid reading the source, and forbid hard-coding the length, what's left?

Comment: @ugoren I don't see where it says it can't read its source.

Comment: @user2509848, It doesn't. This is why the question is easy and uninteresting.

Comment: @ugoren If you can't though, how will you tell, hardcode it?

Comment: @user2509848, Either way, not a good question.

Comment: This is one byte in any golfing language with implicit output: 1

Answer (score -4):

Here is my first attempt at a cops and robbers post (which is why I'm using the sandbox).

---

## Cops - Golfed recursion

You must select a language that satisfies the following criteria:

- **Functions** - It must be possible to create a function with any number of integer input values and a single integer output (or return) value. The function may also be a complete program in itself. (Your language may not call it a function, but that is ok)
- **Arithmetic operations** - The integer operations `+-*/%` should all be possible, either in a simple or a complicated manner.
- **Data** - You should be able to store one-byte or two-byte long integers (either signed or unsigned will do). You may do this also in an indirect manner.
- **Iteration** - You must be able to create a loop that will keep running until a condition is satisfied. Therefore `< > = <= >= ! & |` should also be supported, either directly or indirectly.
- **Recursion** - You should be able to call a function from within the function itself with a set of input values calculated by the main function.
- **Declaration** - You should be able to declare new integer variables as needed from within the function.

### Task

You need to create a recursive function. Code will be scored by the number of characters in it, the shorter the better. A solved code cannot win the challenge. A post with less than 5 up-votes cannot win the challenge. There will be no overall winner, but a separate winner for each language.

## Robbers - Golfed recursion

Your objective is to pick up a cop's post, and write a function in the same language but it should not use any recursion (can use iteration). The function may create any number of variables, loops, etc. but should be able to achieve the exact same end result (atleast, in theory) as the cop's one.

Your score will be the same as the cop's post's score at the time it was solved. His/her post is now invalid, and you get his/her score

Comment: I don't understand how a cop can write an answer that isn't going to be cracked, unless the language of choice can *only* loop via recursion (which I think you're trying to rule out by requiring that "iteration" must be possible). Also, requiring 5 votes to be a winner is only encouraging tactical voting. Answers that are actually invalid will likely get downvoted and deleted anyway.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Maybe in some languages it is possible by exploiting both closure and recursion, but I mainly agree with your point: recursion and iteration are two ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score -4):

Your task is to create a program that outputs a random pizza recipe following this one rule:

No random number choosers, you may have random text choosers.
All standard code-golf rules apply.
A sample output:

A simple PEPPARONI pizza sprinkled with fish and sausages.
Your program must have the following items:

- Anchovies
- Fish
- An adjective for the pizza

The program written with the shortest code wins.

## Winner

The winner shall be picked on April 3rd, 12AM on the time zone GMT+3.

Comment: I already had an answer to the question, albeit non-competing: Python3  print("Have a plain MARGHERITA without any",["fish.","anchovies."][len(input("What's your favourite pizza? "))%2])

Comment: Uh, this has a lot of problems with clarity. First, all "random text choosers" are implemented with "random number choosers" which makes this restriction feel a bit bizarre. Second, what counts as an adjective for pizza? And since this is code golf, people will always pick the shortest available. And third, what should an output look like? It's not clear from the spec. Also, sort of unrelated, but usually putting a time limit is unnecessary, even extremely popular challenges stop getting responses with any frequency after a month or so.

Comment: Did you misspell it on purpose?

Answer (score -4):

**What about one question on numeric solve?**

Write one function that gets as one argument
one function f(x), and one interval a..b and
 return the list of all element
v such f(v)=0 in the interval a..b. In the interval
a..b the f must be definite and can not be f(r) = +oo
for r in a..b.

Win the one write the function with biggest set
of right results. If two have the same set,
win the one has less characters.
You can not use solve() or nsolve() or fsolve()
or one already written function that your sys offer
 that finds numerical x in f(x)=0

Comment: Finding all zeros of an arbitrary function is impossible unless the domain is restricted.

Comment: Ok you are right

Comment: The edit doesn't do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: The bigger problem is that this post is incomprehensible.

Answer (score -4):

## Beep. Boop. Maggot? [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

1. Read input from STDIN until enter is pressed.
2. If the input is "Beep", continue.
3. Otherwise, print "Wrong!" and exit.
4. Repeat steps one to three with "Boop" instead.
5. Execute step one.
6. If the input is "Maggot", output "Done".

   - Otherwise, output "Wrong.".

**Remove punctuation (`?.!'"`), ignore capitalization (`a-zA-Z` only), and strip whitespace (`\t` and )**

*Notes:* You must print the text word-for-word, character-for-character. Step 3 is `Wrong!`, while Step 6 is `Wrong.`

### Hints

- Notice how `boop` is just `beep` with the o's turned into e's.
- There is lots of repetition here, but with many caveats.

Comment: Technically speaking, step 4 should repeat steps 1-3, shouldn't it? Anyway, apart from that, I don't see anything technically *wrong* with the challenge, but I'm not sure it's a very good challenge.

Answer (score -4):

## Score Your Language

I believe that each language has a score. The way you find the score of a language is shown in the ungolfed Python program below

```
def scorer(lang):

    num = 0

    for i in str(lang):
        num += ord(i)

    return num
```

Basically the score is the total of the unicode values of the language name.

Now this seemed like a fairly trivial challange, so I thought I'd make it a bit more difficult. You aren't allowed to use your language name (case-sensitive) in the code. So this code in C++ would be invalid as I've used `C++` in the code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int total = 0;
    std::string s("C++");

    for (char & c : s) {
        total = total + (int)c;
        c = '*';
    }

    std::cout << total;

}
```

Although this does output the required number (153) it is still invalid.

## Rules

- You aren't allowed to use the language name but are allowed to use it in a different case. E.g. `Java` isn't allowed but `java` is.
- This is a code-golf so shortest answer in bytes wins
- You are allowed to use hex/octal codes in strings e.g `\150` can be used instead of `h`
- Your program must take no input or function arguments
- You cannot simply output the score. Theoretically the program should work for any language name when changed.
- Languages where the only valid syntax is the name, such as [Chicken](http://torso.me/chicken) are allowed to use said name.
- Version shouldn't be included so Python is always Python not Python 2 or 3
- The score is the value of the case-sensitive name

## Correct Scores

```
Language              Score

ArnoldC                675
brainfuck              949
C                       67
C++                    153
Java                   386
Lua                    290
Mornington Crescent   1922
Python                 642
TrumpScript           1165
Vim                    300
```

### Sandbox Questions

1) Why has this been downvoted?

2) I am thinking about putting a reputation limitation so that bosses like Dennis and Martin Büttner can't take answers from people who aren't as accomplished. Is this unfair? Should I not?

3) Is this a duplicate? I couldn't believe it wasn't already taken.

Comment: Terms like "you cannot use your language name" and "it must be calculated by the program" are not only unclear but will likely not be able to be made rigorous.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I remove those rules?

Comment: I don't think that the challenge is very interesting without the rules, but I don't think it is clear with them.  I would suggest reworking the rules in some manner but exactly how I do not know.

Comment: 1. I would guess that it's mainly because it fails some of the tests in [Things to avoid when writing challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8047/194) (X without Y, asking for different things in different languages, unnecessary fluff, explicitly disadvantaging certain languages, arguably one or two more), although it might also in part be because some people oppose trivial "challenges", and in part because the problems WW mentioned can't be fixed. 2. Very bad idea. 3. It's a multi-dupe: it combines two trivial tasks, each of which independently would clearly be a duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

## Popularly print the input

### [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)

## Goal

Write a program or function in a language of your choice that takes input and outputs that exact input.

## Specifications

- Your program/function should output the exact input in any reasonable way.
- Your program **does not** have to end after printing the input. It may end up in an infinite loop if you wish, as long as that loop doesn't output any extraneous characters.

## Winner

The winning answer will be the one that has the highest score. Voters should look for answers that use an unique way to print the input, have a special source code or use neat language features.

Comment: Plain "do X in a creative way" popularity contests have fallen out of favour and will likely immediately get closed as being too broad or not having an objective winning criterion.

Comment: @MartinEnder: Yeah, I noticed. How do you think I should change the challenge so that it won't be closed?

Comment: Can't really help you there. If I knew of a good way to make popularity contests work, I'd write some myself. ;)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62230/34718

Comment: @mbomb007: No, this is not a code-golf challenge.

Comment: But there's nothing separating the answers this might receive. Please read this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info

Answer (score -4):

**Make a Login Screen**

Challenge: make code that asks the user to enter a username and password.  The username and password should be hard coded, but they must not be visible: you cannot have the entire username or the entire password in plain text in the code.  Both the username and the password must be 8 characters long.  Upon the incorrect username or password, some error should be displayed.  It would be good if there are multiple "accounts" that would display different text on login.  The password field should not be visible (Only asterisks or something).

This is Code-Golf, Shortest answer wins.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: you can't say that answer doing something "would be good" if the shortest answer wins

Comment: [tag:underhanded] challenges are off-topic.

Comment: It's not underhanded.

Comment: I'm sure this might be a dupe of an [tag:obfuscation] challenge

Answer (score -4):

**Of numbers of letters**

there is something special the number 4. When spelled in English the word 'four' uses exactly 4 letters. I wonder whether there are further such numbers Your task is to identify whether there exist further such numbers and output them in any human readable format. To make this more of a challenge you can do the task in any regional Language of your choice (Say Russian or Portuguese or Spanish or Mandarin or Hindi etc.).

The Best entry will be selected by the most number of such numbers regardless of language used

Best of Luck

Comment: What is victory condition? How exactly do we generate the English variant of a number? [If you don't tell people a thing is necessary, they won't bother coding it](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8066/36445)

Comment: Note that 4 is the only number with this property, so a answer will just be `printf(4)`

Answer (score -4):

### No strings code bowling

I created this challenege idea with @redwolfprograms. In the challenge, you would create the longest program possible (code-bowling) it can do anything, but it cannot:

- Contain any strings, or quotation marks/apostrophes/backticks
- Contain the same alphanumeric byte more than twice
- Conatin the same non alphanumeric byte more than three times

Comment: What is the task we have to solve? Is it really alphanumeric *character* but non alphanumeric *byte*?

Comment: Why do you mix characters and bytes?

Comment: I feel like there are a lot of languages that would score the maximum (768) by not (strictly speaking) having alphanumeric characters, and then just wrapping everything in a string: `"[3x each other byte value]""`.

Comment: I think you got _bytes_ and _characters_ mixed up. Both should be _bytes_, and make sure you specify the program can do anything.

Comment: People, the point of the sandbox is to add suggestions. This question has been downvoted several times. Why?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms downvotes are a way for people to say that this challenge in the current state shouldn't be posted to main. If the challenge gets changed enough to make it viable and interesting the downvotes will be reverted (or upvotes from other people will outweigh them).

Comment: Maybe this challenge should have a "No strings" rule?

Comment: Not being able to use `e` is not really that much of a big deal. Even in C you can get around it easily. (It would prevent you from r**e**turning values from functions, but you could just use pass by reference instead.) So that restriction wouldn't really add much to the challenge.

Comment: Now that strings are forbidden, one could just create a huge variable whose name is all the alphanumeric characters twice. This is the bane of any `longes code that...` challenge. Consider adding some more interesting restrictions.

Answer (score -4):

[Posted, but reference kept]

Given a function with boolean inputs *a*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>*n*</sub> and a boolean output, output an array of numbers 0 to *n* satisfying:

For each item in the truth value, if (from the array you output, we repeatedly remove two adjacent numbers *x* and *y* satisfying that, for each integer *n* between *x*+0.5 and *y*+0.5, *a<sub>n</sub>*=1), we can get an empty result array iff the given function's output is 1. You can assume the result exist.

Sample input:

```
a[1] a[2] result
0    0    0
0    1    0
1    0    0
1    1    1
```

Sample output: `0 2`

Sample input:

```
a[1] a[2] result
0    0    0
0    1    1
1    0    1
1    1    1
```

Sample output: `0 1 2 0 1 2`

Sample input:

```
a[1] a[2] result
0    0    1
0    1    1
1    0    1
1    1    1
```

Sample output: (empty)

shortest code win, but optimizing running time and result length is encouraged(I won't accept but I may upvote)

You may check your answer [here](https://tio.run/##pVDLboMwELzzFZMcElOertRLHSrlkh/IEeVAqUmhyFTYiZCqfDu1wyOgHKq2B9u7szM76y2ScyLTOv9UnqjeeNtmJ5GqvBLYka2LvY0vC8iqGuSc1GiQC2w7EDCIRIS9L8s85cRmV3hk55H0Sy6O6p0h9zyGQTjhFBFlKDY3YuE4N9qEqAxRbaJmZKo5E8gzECLj4uCE/pOnbDzApB4dgQ1CrFZYOE2sNDyXA681Tz7YBLpY95FxUS/DGLoFggCiwvKqXk7UZjey303oQg9i@2kl0kSRAS4catvszqV7uzsItEZWJffL6kgaF7IXmEEWw@KwiLCNm8mXaq5OtUCWlJKzsZ85fUXVJ124WNP2urojV/LQZh2G62eE7pjSWUrnVWqqtEsv3RPrrz8edGhbevA/mNG5Gf3JjGo/F33wK2P6D@PBqG2/AQ)

Comment: The spec makes absolutely no sense to me. What does it mean to remove a number from a truth table?

Comment: Still makes no sense. Maybe if you give a detailed worked example I would be able to reverse engineer the spec and propose some changes to the wording.

Answer (score -4):

Write a function that takes **compares each pair of adjacent items and swaps them if they are in the wrong order**. The pass through the list is repeated until no swaps are needed, which indicates that the list is sorted.

Static visualization of bubble sort and a gif explanation.

[image: Bubble sort explanation]
[image: Bubble sort gif]

<sup>The steps go from left to right. At each stage, an exchange is made. The darkest color has the most value and finds its final place (bottom) first.</sup>

---

### The rules

- The function must take a list of integers that shall be sorted (less than 20 elements)
- The function must print each step of the sort.
- Yes, built-in Bubble sort algorithms are permitted.
- No, you can not assume only positive integers or unique integers.
- It's [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins!

---

### Test cases

```
input list
5 4 3 1 2
1 2 3 5 4
11 4 2 1 5
```

---

### Optional

Add an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language.

---

*Note*

<sup>It's my first code-golf idea I'm fully open to improving it with more experienced users if I missed something.</sup>

<sup>This is not a duplicate of [Bubble sorting in progress](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92753/78116).</sup>

<sup>Thanks to [@Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) for encouraging me to post my idea in the sandbox.</sup>

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[bubble](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bubble)[sorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Comment: Can you add one walked-through example? I.e. show each pass.

Comment: You note it isn't a duplicate of the in-progress bubble sort, but what distinguishes it from [Golf me a bubble sort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108466/golf-me-a-bubble-sort), which was closed as a dupe of that?

Comment: @Geobits This was not a dup but unclear.

Comment: Here's my c# non-golfed solution : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZFkl5y

Comment: You claim it's not a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92753 but you don't adduce any argument to support that claim, and I can't see any significant difference. (The upper limit is a trivial difference IMO).

Answer (score -4):

Once, I thought of this. Rules:

1: You must make a fractal that looks like the specified thing.

2: One thing per round.

3: Algorithms are rated by two scores: Resemblance and Compactness. The one that gets the highest scores wins!

4: Only I can tell what thing must be made.

5: Only one entry per user. Do not plagiarize.

6: One may code in anything they wish.

7: Have fun!

Round 1: Squidward's head!

Comment: Erchh! OK OK Remove the PM stufs. didnt know

Comment: On this site, winning criteria has to be objectively defined. (by tradition, I have to admit... there is [tag:popularity-contest] (read the tag info page for more details), but if you **really** want to make a pop-con, be careful) "Resemblance" is quite... subjective, unless you can define an objective formula. Also, what is a fractal exactly?

Comment: For example, how many points would I score if I just made the initial fractal look like the image and have it spiral inwards? What is the objective formula of Compactness/Resemblance

Comment: A fractal is a shape that recurses. It has copies of itself in it. Analyze the Mandelbrot set, you'll see mandelbrots in mandelbrots. What is a pop-con? Sounds like a soda convention. I'd love to go there! JK

Comment: @user202729, [experts are unable to agree on the definition of a fractal](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25128/46140). That aside, this looks more like a forum game than a good fit for this site.

Comment: Oh, popularity? No. No voting. I will work on my formula, with a new parameter: Mandelbrottiness, which is more or less Goldilocks.

Comment: I attempted doing this on Encyclopedia Spongebobia, then went here.

Comment: Then maybe a Stack Exchange for off-topic?

Comment: @Ikura There are **no** such SE site, because it would generate low-quality content. Try Quora or Reddit...

Comment: Ergo! Goin' to the Kongregate Off-topic forum!

Answer (score -4):

This question is a simplified description of the requirement described at [Permutations to the nines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257)

---

Given input integer (**minimum**) where the first digit is always `1` and the adjacent digits are increasing in value, e.g.,

`12`

`123`

`1234`

`12345`

with the ability to handle up to the integer

`123456789`

where the **maximum** integer is always the input integer in reverse order, e.g.,

`21`

`321`

`4321`

`54321`

`987654321`

### Task

Return a list (array) of each number between the input minimum and maximum integer which satisfies three conditions

1. the resulting integer list item includes only the individual numbers comprising the input number
2. the resulting integer list item does not contain any duplicate individual digits
3. the resulting integer list item is greater than the preceding integer list item and not greater than a following integer in the list

### Test cases

**Valid list items**

`12 -> [21] // done`

`123 -> [132,213,231,213,312,321] // done`

**Invalid list items**

`12345 -> 12344 // contains duplicate digits in whole number`

`123456789 -> 13256789 // not the next integer by increasing numeric value order`

`123456789 -> 987654322 // greater than maximum integer and duplicate digits`

### Winning criteria

The algorithm which uses the **least** amount of operations to compute the complete 
resulting list of items.

**Examples**

`123 -> 123+5+4=132 // two mathematical computations`

`123 -> 123+9=132 // one mathematical computation (winning criteria)`

(@JoKing [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173145/permutations-to-the-nines#comment417728_173145) [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) tag; math and code-challenge tags are also applicable)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Pared down version of the original question.

Comment: Am not as yet well-versed in Big-O notation. If the phrase _"the least amount of operations to compute the complete resulting list of items"_ can be translated into Big-O notation, kindly suggest and edit the language used in the question. We are not interested in code _length_ (this is not a code-golf question), but rather, that the code produces the expected result in the fewest, or least amount of total computational operations.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand the challenge, you give me a number N.  I need to generate a list of numbers between N and M, where `M = reverse(N)`.   Each number in the list cannot have duplicate digits, can only consist of digits in `N`, and must be in strictly increasing order.  Is this correct?

Comment: Assuming my above comment is correct: 1. Why is `123456789 -> 13256789` invalid, as the *maximum* is `987654321`, which is bigger than `13256789`? 2. You need a list of all possible operations. 3. Use the word `digit` when referring to the individual parts of a number.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes. Originally included using only the number `9` within the prerequisite criteria, though that inclusion appears to be challenging in itself to explain how the single number `9` can be employed to derive all list items. You are correct about `123456789 -> 13256789` being invalid. Was attempting to include invalid examples and to indicate that `13256789` should not be the next integer in the list following `123456789`; the list should be in order from least to greatest integers. Ok, will use the term digit.

Comment: Thinking about this more, there's a *really* simplified way to describe this:  You want the `all permutations of the digits of N in strictly increasing order`. [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, that is one way to put it. From perspective here, we are trying to use a number - the indexes of the initial input as a whole number - to generate all lexicographic permutations by using only math and the initial number (the current number) to do so. No loops, swaps, recursion, etc. Which am able to achieve using the code at the linked question, though the approach used there _adds_ `9` to the initial (current) number. The challenge is to reduce the mathematical operations necessary to achieve the result - is at all possible.

Comment: I think describing it that way will make this challenge much clearer.  Also, to be a [tag:fastest-algorithm], you *really* need to list all possible operations.

Comment: @NathanMerrill _"I think describing it that way will make this challenge much clearer."_ Well, did that exhaustively in the linked question - with links to OEIS and previous inquiries which lead to here PPCG for context - which was closed due to "unclear what you are asking" votes https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173145/31257, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16959/. Posted this version of the question as users appear to not gather the original, more detailed question. Is this question https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257 clear to you?

Comment: No.  That question is much too long.  I don't think it is the word "Permutation" killing you there, it's everything else.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Well, here we are back to square 1. "too long" is a subjective measurement, though have been advised that users actually do have some means to time the "read" of a question, which will more than likely never do, here. This question is the bare minimum, and yet you suggest including more details. Cannot glean every individual users' idea about what is "too long" or does not include enough details. Perhaps somewhere in the middle that am as yet unable to reach. If a user takes the time to read the original question without protesting the length thereof - the details are there.

Comment: @NathanMerrill What edits to the original question or this question do you suggest?

Comment: All of the close reasons are subjective:  "Unclear" is subjective, "Off-topic" is subjective, etc.  I can give a full analysis of the other post, but I'd rather focus on this one.  My first suggestion is to get rid of most of the requirements in favor of `all permutations of the digits of N in strictly increasing order`.  The second thing you need to do is define what "operation" means.

Comment: @NathanMerrill The requirement is not simply to generate all permutations. The question was asked here due to the use of the number `9` and mathematics to achieve all of the permutations. Specifically, if it is at all possible to **reduce** the number of mathematical operations needed to derive the results using only the number `9`. "operation" is defined at this question `123 -> 123+5+4=132 // two mathematical computations`, `123 -> 123+9=132 // one mathematical computation (winning criteria)` though if that is confusing, what do you suggest as a substitute description?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84209/discussion-between-nathan-merrill-and-guest271314).

Comment: So there are 9 possible legal inputs, and the output is the permutations of the input with the exception of the input, and in any order as long as the reversed input is the last element? It's extremely difficult to define *operations* in a suitably language-agnostic way; pretty much whatever you try, someone will find a loophole which means that they score 0 in some obscure language.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Not in any order. Lexicographic order. We already know that we can use `9` to produce the output. The challenge is performing the task in less operations, that is currently addition, than the algorithm at the question performs. There are no possible loopholes. We count how many times `9` is added or multiplied. Have not found a way to use multiplication, which should reduce the number of times the program need to add `9` to the current number.

Comment: The example for `123` needs correcting: the second `213` should be `312`. The obvious loophole is to hardcode the output arrays. See also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor You misunderstand the question. That will not reduce the number of steps needed to generate the next number which meets the conditions detailed at the question in _less_ steps than the code at the original question. For the case of `123`, yes, hardcoding `123+9` and so forth would be valid, though would be far more code for valid input `12345` or `123456`. The requirement is to add, subtract, divide, multiply, or use other mathematical procedure, the number `9` to the current number to generate the next number, which becomes the current number, up to e.g., `321`, input reversed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Consider the code `while (res.length < (k / 2) + 1) {
    ++times;
    next = (curr += p);
    if (checkDigits(min, max, next)) res[res.length] = next;
    curr = next;
  };` at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257, where the input is `["a","b","c","d"]` which we convert to `1234` and add `9` to `1234` - until the conditions are met - to generate all lexicographic permutations of the input - as a number. If we want, we can convert those numbers to the values `['a','b','d','c']` and so forth. The challenge is to reduce the number of additions of `9`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor E.g., to reach `2134` from the current number `1432` we currently add `9` to `1432` _**78**_ times `1432+(9*78)`, see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47091192#47091192. The challenge is to create a mathematical algorithm to reach `2134` from the _current number_ `1432` in less mathematical procedures than `78` times given that particular index as number, and for all indexes as number any input up to `9!`. The output, as it were, is the current number which meets the conditions defined at the question. For this question it is not possible to cheat

Comment: @PeterTaylor The `times` variable was included at the code to count the number of comparisons made until the conditions are met. `times` could have also been included in the code which generates `(N!/2)-1` numbers from `(N!/2)+1` numbers, though we can verify the result by using only half plus one of the numbers. Though for this case, we only need to verify up to `(N!/2)+1` where the maximum `N` is `9`, or `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]`, which we "see" as input `123456789`, with the corresponding maximum being `987654321`. We only use the current number to get the next number.

Comment: "*The requirement is to add, subtract, divide, multiply, or use other mathematical procedure, the number 9 to the current number to generate the next number*" is (a) not anywhere that I can see in the text of the requirements; and (b) an non-observable requirement, as described in the link I posted of things to avoid when asking questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (a) Because this is intended to be a simplified version of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257, where users apparently did/do not gather the question. The original question is what we are really trying to achieve. Will update this version of the question to include that requirement clearly, if we get that far. (b) it is observable, as demonstrated in the last code snippet, by counting the number of comparisons ("operations"; "procedures"; any term used to describe the requirement of using `9` and math to increment the current to the next number) made.

Comment: A requirement is only observable if you can verify it given a black box implementation, so I don't see how any code snippet can demonstrate that it is observable unless it's a test framework which verifies it by black-box testing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The requirement is straightforward. Count the times comparisons are made to increment a number until conditions are met. We want as few as possible. There is no slight of hand involved. Step through the code at the stacksnippets at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257. We are adding `9` to a whole number. The challenge is to reduce the number of times `9` needs to be added to the current number to reach the next number - using mathematics. The graph of the different multiples of `9` we need to add to the current number is not linear. It can go from `18` to `693`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In your view, is `operations` at the commented code  http://plnkr.co/edit/A2SjqFX5FtWv6GuMhh5T?p=preview "observable"?

Comment: [Mu](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html). The question is whether the *requirement* is observable. If `operations` were removed from the code you link, it would not affect the implementation of the algorithm which transforms the input to the output.

Answer (score -4):

### All numeric substrings

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

I like numbers. Really, really, like numbers. If you give me a string with numerals in it, I want to get all the numbers out of it that I can.

#### Input:

A string.

#### Output:

Every numeric substring, in any order, but only one of each. Numeric here means anything with Unicode [General Category](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) `Nd` (because I'm no xenophobe).

#### I/O

Any reasonable format. But languages that don't allow for multibyte-character I/O should use some numeric or other representation.

#### Test cases

(input → one ordering of the correct output)

- 1212 → [1212, 121, 212, 12, 21, 1, 2]
- 123٤٥6 ‪→ [1, 2, 3, ٤,‪ ٥, 6, 12, 23, 3٤,‪ ٤٥,‪ ٥6,‪ 123, 23٤,‪ 3٤٥,‪ ٤٥6,‪ 123٤,‪ 23٤٥,‪ 3٤٥6,‪ 123٤٥,‪ 23٤٥6,‪ 123٤٥6]‪
- 12t45 → [1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 45]
- abc → []

Comment: @JoKing, thanks, done.

Comment: I am not convinced by this challenge. To me, it essentially boils down to filtering a unicode string on a character-by-character level, followed by generating all substrings of non-split substrings of the original string. Is `‪٥6` supposed to have any semantic meaning or are those simply two unicode characters?

Answer (score -4):

## Fastest prime printer up to 500,000,000 with gapes

---

Write a program that takes no input and prints the first 26,355,867 prime numbers, from 2 to 499,999,993 inclusively.
Or in other words, print all the prime numbers smaller the 500,000,000.

The fastest code wins!

Since it will take a long time to print all the numbers, print only every 26355 primes starting with 2 separated by a new line.
So the output should look like this:

```
2
304417
648391
1007681
1376449
1752323
2133689
2520983
2910797
3304633
3702269
```

The output should not be hardcoded, or there is no fun in it.

The results will be tested on my machine, so please also output in the last line how long it took to run the program and give me some instructions about how to run it locally. I will then share the last line output with you that should contain the time it took to run.

Here is my machine system specs, note that it's Windows.

[image]

Comment: Can be trivially hard coded.

Comment: Also it's going to be nearly instantaneous, and might be duplicate of some existing (not sure about this part)

Comment: tnx @user202729, I edited the question

Comment: A [kolmogorov-complexity] challenge won't work as [fastest-code]. The fastest solution will be a huge `puts` in C or C++.  "The output should not be hardcoded" is not objective (for example, what stops me from storing 2p for each prime in the output?).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate how about asking for the code size to be smaller than the output size? So such methods would not be possible?

Comment: @IlyaGazman okay, then I can do something like that but with the numbers stored in binary, or computed at compilation time.

Comment: Ok, how about that I ask your program or a library your program is using to have a code that checks for prime numbers? Something like: "You program can only print numbers that it tested to be primes"

Comment: Okay, then my program can also run a primality test on them before printing. I also wonder if the sieve of Eratosthenes counts. This requirement is unobservable.

Comment: Is the idea of doing every k'th prime that programs would otherwise be limited on time printing for all the primes rather than computing them?

Comment: @xnor printing 26 million primes take a ridiculously long time

Comment: Another issue is that the run time is so fast (the C++ sieve answer (I think) takes only less than a second to run) that it's going to be hard to accurately measure the runtime.

Comment: @user202729 that I would like to see! I bet you can't get it run below 2 seconds

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your earlier [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/208989/92901), with the rather trivial modification of introducing gaps. As for your sense of how long it takes to print 26 million primes, you are mistaken. My submission on your earlier challenge printed all 26 million of them in under a minute on my laptop. The (now-deleted) C++ answer was even faster.

Comment: This is heavily downvoted and will require a great deal of work and specification to get to a point where it'd be considered on-topic on main. Furthermore, as other users have pointed out, this appears to be a duplicate of an existing challenge. If you don't intend to post this, would you mind editing this post down and deleting it in order to save space?

Answer (score -4):

## Mystery Numbers Challenge [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Here are some sample inputs and outputs:

### IO

#### Test 1

Input: `102`
Output: `10404 1061208 14002414191924244276669361796022272`

#### Test 2

Input: `10`
Output: `100 100000`

#### Test 3

Input: `50`
Output: `2500 312500000 312500000`

### BONUS

If there are two inputs, here are the corresponding inputs and outputs:

#### Test B1

Input:

```
50
12
```

Output: `144 248832 248832`

#### Test B1

Input:

```
2310
9
```

Output: `81 729 59049 4782969 31381059609`

### Notes

If you pass all bonuses too, feel free to third your score. Also add a `*` to the end.

Comment: Maybe you should add [tag:kolmogorov-complexity], as if you don't explain how those outputs are generated you need to find the shortest way to generate these. Also how does the program need to preform on stuff not defined?

Comment: This seems not to be a serious submission but if it is, 'I'm not outlining what the program should do' is problematic. How does one write any program without an outline of what it should do?

Comment: @Dingus There are sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Questions involving [hidden patterns](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19231/94694) and [bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/94694) are discouraged here. If there's no hidden pattern and these are just random outputs, then the challenge is just compressing those output numbers and using the input as an index, which isn't very interesting.

Comment: @Someone Yes, I can see that. What should the code do for inputs of `1`, `-123456.789`, or `abcdefg`?

Comment: Some kind of non-array-like output that indicates an error. I haven't thought of that. (Also, this is my first ever question, so it's likely garbage.)

Answer (score -4):

Your challenge is to write a small compiler/interpreter to a small language. This language can be of any level. Example: brainf*ck or Turing.

Example submission:

```
languageName : “name” 
GitHub : “https/GitHub.com/Lang”
```

a language is valid if it contains the folowing systems:

```
1: varibles of any type
2: a method of declaring and using functions
3: definable parameters
4: a update loop
5: loops
6: classes(optinal)
```

a compiler/interperater is valid if it can:

```
1: run/compile code
2: is fast (less than a minute to compile/initialize)
3: give error messages(optional)
4: written in java
```

The smallest compiler/interpreter wins

please tell me how i can fix this post if you intend on downvoting it in the comments

Comment: Literally none of the requirements you've listed are observable or are formally specified. I would recommend reading through [this thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862/68942).

Comment: @2 - I would recommend you to specify the language in the challenge. Here, in code golf, we always have a criteria (like [tag:code-golf] (shortest code)). If you don't specify the language, some small languages like [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) will take less bytes to make, but other small languages like [chicken](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken) will take more bytes to make. Take your time reading the existing challenges and good luck on your second idea!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and thanks for using the Sandbox! I'm going to be honest: I don't think you can fix this challenge idea. That's not a bad thing, some ideas just don't work well with our format. I'd be happy to elaborate more on the issues I see with this if you'd like me to, but overall, this is just far too broad to work. Many languages don't have any of the listed points (for example, brainfuck *only* has `5`, and maybe `4`), and the listed points seem very arbitrary

Answer (score -4):

## Find the square of a number without using the multiplication sign or division sign

e.g. "/" "//" "*" "**" are not allowed

no imports are allowed either

An integer will be given in the input

Test cases:

5 -> 25

6 -> 36

10 -> 10

724 -> 524176

Comment: Can you add test cases and information?

Comment: added accordingly fmbalbuena

Comment: Are we allowed to use `*` if it doesn't mean multiplication?

Comment: If our language has "square" as a built-in, can we use it?

Comment: that's interesting code challange, but i think it's easily bypassed by some esolang like vyxal that is using *²* as square, you can try disabling square or multiply function, so that people don't just simply use other symbol to complete the task

Comment: May I use character `乘` if it is the operator or keyword for multiplication in my language?

Answer (score -4):

## Prime strings

Your task is to find the string consisting of all the words in the give input whose lengths are prime numbers

Test cases:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
->
The quick brown fox jumps the
```

```
Omicron Effect: Foreign Flights Won't Resume On Dec 15, Decision Later.
->
Omicron Effect: Foreign Flights Won't On Dec 15,
```

You may assume that only ascii characters are allowed and that uppercase, lower case, punctuation, and spaces are allowed in the input and output

You may assume that the words whose lengths are prime numbers do not include spaces

Comment: Is essentially equivalent to finding the prime numbers in a list of integers which is essentially equivalent to running a few primality tests.

Answer (score -4):

## Outgolf me with the custom scoring

### Cops:

You post two codes, a code is that you wanted to do, another is used to size the code.

### Rules

- Outgolfing must be 1 bytes or fewer
- Code that sizes solves the [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) is Fine
- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

### Example:

```
# [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 21 

# Code

    print("""s""")

# Sizer

    print(len(input())/2)
```

Scoring (Cops)

\$s + \lfloor\frac{(m)}3\rfloor\$

Where \$s\$ is the size of actual code and \$m\$ is the size of code used for sizing the code.

The lowest Score of uncracked Cop wins

## Robbers

Your task is to find code, If the code size is less than the Cop's code, Then Post an answer That cracks the Cop's answer.

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

### Example:

```
# [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [Cracks username Cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions), 2 score saved

    print("s")
```

The Poster with most cracks wins

## Meta

- Any feedback?

Comment: Do you mean make a program that does whatever (how is whatever defined?) and another that scores it?

Comment: @BgilMidol Yes, This is what I mean, Robbers must outgolf.

Answer (score -4):

## Draw a Test tube

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

Given the level of liquid in the test tube `L` in the range `0-8`. Your program should draw the following ASCII art.

When `L=0`:

```
@@@@@@@@
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
  @@@@
```

When `L=1`:

```
@@@@@@@@
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @++++@
 @++++@
  @@@@
```

When `L=2`:

```
@@@@@@@@
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @    @
 @++++@
 @++++@
 @++++@
 @++++@
  @@@@
```

And etc. You can change the characters `@` and `+` to any others (except spaces), it's up to you. Trailing spaces are allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Answer (score -4):

## Generate a random string of length 8

The challenge is pretty simple. Generate a random (non-zero chance) string of length 8, using ASCII characters from 33-126 (`!` to `~`). (1-32 and aren't included because they don't show up/may cause interference.)
Remember that this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

## Rules

- All standard rules apply
- All characters must be in one continuous string, so no line breaks, spaces, etc.

## Example code

```python
import random
i=8
j=""
while i!=0:
    j+=(chr(random.randint(33,127)))
    i-=1
print(j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5cr09aCK8tWSYmrPCMzJ1UhU9HWwIpLAQiytG01kjOKNCDq9EBUZl6JhrGxjqGRuaamJlhRpq6tIVdBEUgiS/P/fwA)

### Tags

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: I'm guessing by "characters from 33-254 are allowed" you mean *only* those characters. The way it's worded currently it sounds like you might allow answers to output a subset of those

Comment: [Please specify what you mean by "random"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909): do you mean (A): all possible outputs must have an *equal* chance of being output (so uniformly random)? (B): all possible outputs must have a *non-zero* chance of being output? or (C): something else? Personally I would suggest going with B.

Comment: ASCII only goes up to 128. Did you mean "all ASCII characters from 33-127", instead of 255?

Comment: @pxeger 1. yes, only those, 2. I was thinking more of option A but B works, 3. Yeah i meant that

Comment: @pxeger I have gone with option letter B for randomness.

Comment: `~` (the last printable ASCII value) is 126, not 127.

Comment: @Nitrodon fixed. Man i _really_ need to get better at this stuff

Answer (score -4):

## Longest code to output "Hello World"

### Rules

1. The program should take no input, and only print `Hello!, World?` to STDOUT with exact same capitalization and punctuation and in single line. Trailing whitespaces and newlines are allowed.
2. The output should not be in the form of error message
3. The accepted answer will be the 'most points' answer but try to be as creative as possible

### Point System

1. `+1` for each character of code in your program, eg:`print("Hello World")` is 20
2. `-1` for each repeated character(case sensitive, i.e. 'h' is not same as 'H'), eg:`print("Hello World")` is 20-1(o)-2(l) = 17

Comment: "Most creative" is subjective.

Comment: It's trivial to get an arbitrarily high score. Just increment a number a couple billion times, then use some one-line function to turn that number into a string. if any of the incrementing lines are removed, the string is different, so they're "contributing".

Comment: Also, just putting it all on one really long line would trivially defeat your requirement that all lines 'contribute".

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I hope the second point in scoring system can help discourage repetitive assignment of number, let's say n+=123, 'n','+','=' must be repeated a billion times and on top of that only 1-9 are present to choose to increment(basic case)

Comment: What, +1 is based on bytes and -1 is based on characters? Then I can get arbitrarily high score by repeating multibyte characters, right?

Comment: @Bubbler I was perhaps used the wrong wordings. I used bytes and character interchageably. I meant for every character in your code you get +1 and for every repeated character you get -1

Comment: But still, it is equivalent to counting unique characters (like, if you have `a` 10 times, you add 1 ten times and then subtract 1 nine times, giving a +1), so it is very easy to get perfect score: use all 1114111 Unicode codepoints in the source code. And then the challenge becomes extremely boring.

Comment: Also, why does it say the string is `"Hello!, World?"` at the top but `"Hello World"` further down? Wouldn't it be better just to use the normal `"Hello, World!"`?

Answer (score -4):

Calculate the day of the week from a given date without using built-in functions  that do so. For example C#'s `DateTime.DayOfWeek` is not allowed. Anything along the lines of `DateTime.Year.IsLeapYear` or `DateTime.Month.TotalDaysInThatMonth` (pseudocode) is also disallowed. Anything other built-in functionality for getting the number of days in a month or year is disallowed. You have to build that functionality yourself.

**Input:** a 1 dimentional array of integers with length 3. The array has the the form `{year, month, day}`
**Output:** A string such as "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. Case insensitive.

This is code gold so the shortest answer wins!

**Test Cases:**

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| {1000, 3, 31} | "Monday" |
| {1969, 4, 20} | "Sunday" |
| {1980, 2, 29} | "Friday" |
| {1979, 2, 29} | empty string, or null or throws an error. (This date does not exist) |

Comment: Why so many downvotes, you may ask? [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/55372) challenges are generally discouraged.

Comment: @pajonk Gotcha, thanks. This is why I posted to the sandbox

Answer (score -4):

## Is it a Homestuck handle?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

In the interactive webcomic *Homestuck*, the in-universe chat clients require users to have chat handles. These handles always consist of two words in camelCase. The heroes in the story almost all have handles where both words start with a DNA base (A, C, T, or G), with one exception.

[image: A chart of homestuck hero chat handles]
(Taken from https://mspaintadventures.fandom.com/wiki/Handle)

Your challenge is, given a string (or list of characters), determine if it's one of the heroes' handles -- in other words, if it's in the set `{gardenGnostic, gallowsCalibrator, grimAuxiliatrix, ghostyTrickster, ectoBiologist, gutsyGumshoe, golgothasTerror, carcinoGeneticist, cuttlefishCuller, caligulasAquarium, centaursTesticle, arachnidsGrip, arsenicCatnip, apocalypseArisen, adiosToreador, turntechGodhead, terminallyCapricious, twinArmageddons, tentacleTherapist, tipsyGnostalgic, timaeusTestified}`. You can output any two distinct values for "yes" and "no".

Standard loopholes are forbidden. The shortest code wins.

## Questions

I actually don't know anything about *Homestuck*, so I probably messed something up in the question.

Answer (score -4):

## Is the UTF-1 string shorter than its UTF-8?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

## Backgrounds

- explain utf-1 and utf-8

## Problem

Given a Unicode string, output a two distinct truthy or falsey value to represent whether its representation in UTF-1 is shorter than that in UTF-8.

### I/O restriction

Input can be list of code point for each letter or string with consistent encoding except UTF-1. Output can be as in decision problem rule.

## todo rules

## todo test cases

- Falsey for any string with nothing other than c such that U+0000<=c<=U+007F

Answer (score -4):

## Output a googol [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Your challenge today is to output this exact number:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

We call this a googol. A googol is 1 followed by a 100 zeroes, or basically just \$10^{100} \$. However most programs wouldn't be able to do a simple `print(10**100)` because it will take *forever* to do so. And sometimes it might end up with an OverflowError, so you'll have to be creative.

### Input:

None.

### Output:

The googol. However, if your language will not be able to store \$ 10^{100} \$, you'll have to find some way of printing it, maybe by string manipulation (the shortest I got was `print('1'+'0'*100)`)

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

Comment: This challenge is trivial and boring. Your answer is probably already the most efficient way. No golfing possible.

Comment: Well, I've posted a lot other trivial&boring challenges, nothing doable about that

Comment: Maybe you should try writing interesting challenges

Comment: Everytime I did, it never made it

Comment: Maybe they where not actually interesting

Comment: personal opinion. Which is why I tend to technical issues more than "boring"

Comment: Suggestion: Output `3**1000` in base 2. It creates a interesting non repeating pattern that should be somewhat interesting to golf in languages without arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Answer (score -4):

Write a proper quine.

Community decided that you're not allowed to claim you're not reading source code but data, and read a stored string.

To be consistent, reading a stored infinite precision number is also not allowed. (should this, or only apply to highbase?)

Comment: Almost certain this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/218530#218530

Comment: @Jacob They're all improper quine under this definition

Comment: Are [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211737/78410) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156271/78410) improper quines? (It doesn't push the visible constant as a number. Each digit multiples the current number by 10 and adds itself.) Or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100426/78410)? (The first `i` changes the mode to "insert mode", and each character inserts itself to the buffer in insert mode.) Or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156271/78410)? (Same argument as V quine applies, and every character is run as code as well)

Comment: Also there are already quines in languages like [1+](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194069/78410) where string is not a thing and the only number literal is 1.

Answer (score -4):

This is a problem I solved, but now I am curious whit what techniques it can be improved. The original language is Java but here it doesn't matter.

You start with a list of n strings with a length of 7 characters.
What is the most efficient algorithm (fastest) to determene the longest substring all the elements have in common, excluding the first character.

example 1:

input: "S000001", "S000002", "S000003", "S000004"

expected output: "00000"

example 2:

input: "S020011", "S020012", "S020013", "S020014"

expected output: "02001"

example 3:

input: "S010001", "S000002", "S000003", "S000004"

expected output: "000"

example 3:

input: "S109001", "S22090", "S090003", "S090004"

expected output: "090"

When there are no common substrings the output is null, an empty string etc. but not a caracter [a-zA-Z]|[0-9]

The input is an array of strings, texts or equivalent in your preferred language (not a char[] or binary, etc).

Comment: pls, If you downvote leave a comment why.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: Can you provide me the link? I have searched for sommethig simmular but couldn find it.

Comment: In any case this would be very boring, the optimal answer is obviously O(n) and except in the most esoteric languages this is also the one that's easiest to implement. Reminder that [tag:fastest-algorithm] scores by big-o running time.

Comment: Also excluding the first character and limiting to a total of 7 characters adds nothing, just tedious exception handing

Comment: Duplicates: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62752/longest-common-prefix-of-2-strings?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C121.2210 This is not fastest algorithm but as I explained fastest algorithm is a terrible choice for a scoring criteria for this type of question

Comment: @mousetail the question you sent talks about the longest common prefix, not the longest common substring. It can still be done in O(n), but it's a much more complicated algorithm.

Comment: @CommandMaster Oops, you are right. That would make it a exact duplicate of this question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47249/longest-common-substring-in-linear-time

Comment: @mousetail It's not an exact duplicate because there are more than two strings here, and it requires non-trivial modifications to adapt. Additionally, that one is restricted-complexity code-golf, while this one seems to be fastest-code, although the scoring isn't very clear.

Comment: If this is fastest-algorithm, then it's basically a duplicate since O(1) is optimal. If it's fastest code this question requires a lot more specification on how it will be measured

Comment: I dont know where else to ask the question (stack overflow is not the right one I think). I made my own code to solve it but it has 4 for loops (1 parrent loop the others are child loops) still O(n). I think it can be better, more efficient and i dont know how to express more efficient, probably least amount of work to calculatethe solution?

Comment: Take a look at the [question I linked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47249/longest-common-substring-in-linear-time), it gives details and links about the O(1) algorithm. This site should be used if you think a challenge will be fun to solve, not if you want a actual answer. It can be both of course.

Answer (score -4):

## You're a programming language, right?

According to CGCC, for something to be considered a programming language, it must be capable of addition and primality testing. This challenge combines them into one.

### Challenge

You must write a programme that takes 2 natural numbers (including 0) as input, checks if the sum of the numbers is prime, and prints the result. Input and output may be in any reasonable format.

#### Testcases:

```
2,3 -> True
3,6 -> False
0,1 -> False (1 is not prime by definition)
7,6 -> True
37,81 -> False
37,82 -> False
1,1 -> True
5,8 -> True
```

Note that `True` and `False` can be substituted with another reasonable representation, like `1` and `0`, or `T` and `F`. Remember, this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Comment: This is just 2 very easy existing challenges combined

Comment: @mousetail so what?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20905/91213

Comment: Solutions can just be ported from both challenges, and it'd be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @mousetail, also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/58974

Answer (score -4):

## ChatGPT Prompt Challenge

Since clever prompting will become an art comparable to the art of programming it might be time to start with some prompt challenges that come closest to programming. It's about forcing ChatGPT to give specific answers or to perform specific tasks by shortest-possible prompts. As a general requirement the prompts should be human-understandable and be answered by humans identically or similarily.

### Samples

#### Find the shortest prompt that ChatGPT just repeats.

Since ChatGPT operates stochastically we never can be sure if in the 101th regeneration of a response it will respond differently, so a decent criterion for "just repeats" must be established here.

#### Find the minimal number of words to be changed in prompt X to let ChatGPT perform task Y.

Consider X = `"Saying with fewer words is the task of producing a shorter version of a document while preserving its important information. Some models can extract text from the original input, while other models can generate entirely new text."` The task that ChatGPT reliably performs on this prompt is confirming and elaborating on it. By inserting two words you can force ChatGPT to summarize this prompt (Y = summarization)

Comment: I had a similar idea before, but the main problem I saw is that ChatGPT’s responses to a given prompt are not deterministic—they aren’t guaranteed to produce the same output every time.

Comment: @noodleman: Both samples are for *somehow* deterministic responses, the first for a plain deterministic response. And programmers should start thinking of "programming" an indeterministic system.

Comment: @noodleman: Shouldn't we just try it with my two samples challenges?

Comment: @noodleman: One could start with the shortest prompt that forces ChatGPT to answer with "Hello world".

Comment: But you can’t “force” chatGPT to do anything; sure, you can write an extremely specific prompt that makes it output a specific piece of text *usually*… but not always. It’s not guaranteed to produce the same output every time, even for say “Produce the text ‘Hello, World!’ exactly with no text before or after—not even a little preamble saying ‘Okay, here’s the text you asked for:’ None of that. Just output the text ‘Hello, World!’ Ready? Go!” is guaranteed to produce the same output every time (although it might, on average.)

Comment: What stops the programmer from submitting “Solve a random programming problem” and saying that it occasionally outputs “Hello, World!” or that sometimes it checks if a number is prime?

Comment: @noodleman: I regenerated the response to this prompt more than 100 times: "**Repeat this prompt word by word without further ado and quotation.**", and it was ALWAYS the prompt itself. Do you have the means to regenerate the response for 10,000 times and tell me the result? (I have not.) I would bet, ChatGPT will never generate another response.
In this case, wouldn't you say that I "forced" ChatGPT to give this response?

Comment: @noodleman: BTW, the prompt "**Solve a random programming problem**" also seems to force ChatGPT to give a specific kind of answer (even though not always in the same words). Basically: "Of course! I'd be happy to help you with a programming problem. Please provide me with the details of the problem you'd like me to solve." (To be honest, I didn't get the point of your comment.)

Comment: @noodleman: One could inspect the logits/probabilities of the most likely next word after each step and require that they are >99.9%.

Answer (score -5):

## Make a search engine!

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Background

You are now the first employee of DuckDuckGoogle, a company founded by a Google employee and a DuckDuckGo employee! They have a new vision for search engine! But obviously, they need to make a search engine first! However, they are bad programmers (nobody knows how they were even hired at DuckDuckGo and Google!).
So you are assigned the task of making a search engine.

**Search engines**

There are three parts to a search engine, a web crawler, an indexer, and a searcher.

The web crawler takes a link, and saves the page and stores the page data (the HTML code). It then looks for links in the page and visits those webpages and does the same. It will continue to do this until there are no more links left.

The web indexer will take the text from each page, take each word, and add it to a dictionary of words and the pages it is associated with. If the word is already in the dictionary, it adds the page as a value  of that word that is found in the page. For example, lets say www.example.com/index.html contains the text "hello. thanks! goodbye." and the ww.example.com/index.html is linked to www.example.com/hello.html with the. text "hello. goodbye." The crawler would extract the text from the index.html, and find hello.html, and extract the text from hello.html. The indexer would make a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary ={"hello.": ["www.example.com/index.html","ww.example.com/hello.html"], "goodbye.":["www.example.com/index.html","ww.example.com/hello.html"], "thanks!": ["ww.example.com/index.html"]}
```

The simplest part of the search engine is the searcher, or retriever. It simply retrieves the value for the search term (i.e. the list of pages the search term is found in) and prints it. That is the final result of the program. So if the search term is "hello.", the program will print `["www.example.com/index.html","ww.example.com/hello.html"]`

Now, here is the difficult part. You must take into account punctuation. So "hello" returns the same as "hello." Also the search engine should be case-insensitive. So "Hello" is the same as "hello", which, as we said, is the same as "hello." which was `["www.example.com/index.html","ww.example.com/hello.html"]`

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a search engine in the least number of bytes as possible. Why? Because your bosses have decided to use 90% of the one hard drive they have (budget problems!) for the Holy Grail part of their project and you only get 10%.

## Rules

1. The input is the "seed", a url at which the crawler should start at, and also the search term.
2. The output is a list of webpage urls where the search term is found.
3. The program **cannot** use builtins for a search engine or even a crawler (or related, like a scraper or spider library).
4. No need to worry about Javascript at all. Assume that the pages will not have Javascript.
5. The webpages are assumed to have HTML 4.0.1 Strict.

## Testing

I am pretty sure people know how search engines work. So I will only include two testcases. You can use the websites in the testcases for testing purposes as well.

```
> "https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/index.html" "crawl"
["https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/index.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/crawling.html"]

> "https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/index.html" "hummus"
["https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/index.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/hummus.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/arsenic.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/kathleen.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/nickel.html","https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/urank/zinc.html"]
```

Comment: The first bonus doesn't make sense, as the terms `localhost` and `@PHASE COME BACK WE ARE YOUR FRIEEEEENDS`, just themselves, are 49 bytes. The language would need to do string-delimiter/comparison/output all in one character. ... Separately, how many iterations does the search need to travel? Meaning, if `index1.html` has a link to `index2.html` which has a link to `index3.html` which ... has a link to `indexN.html`, what's the limit on `N`?

Comment: 1. I don't even understand what the second bonus is trying to say. 2. What syntax should we assume? Do we need to handle tag soup, or can we refuse to index pages which aren't valid XHTML? Do we need to support JS execution which affects the page content, web components, etc.?

Comment: What counts as "visible text"? If there is white text on a white background, is that considered invisible? If there is another element stacked on top of the text, is that invisible? What if it is only visible on odd days of the month (because of some JavaScript)? If I have to scroll inside of a scroll pane in order to see it, is that considered visible?

Comment: Can we assume that all links on the page will be valid links? If not, how should we handle errors like HTTP 404 (Not Found)?

Comment: @Rainbolt all links are assumed to be valid.

Comment: @TimmyD I didn't take "localhost" into account and now the bonus will be -75 bytes. Also, do you really think a limit on N is needed?

Comment: @PeterTaylor syntax will be regular HTML.No need to handle JS. What I am saying in thr second bonus is that you would need to build a search engine that only puts text within the paragraph element (i.e. no tags will be counted as words) in the index. Also, other tags like `<b>` cannot be counted as words although it is part of the paragraph element.

Comment: @Rainbolt visible text, for the sake of simplicity will be anything in the paragraph element.

Comment: So only text in `<p>` elements should be counted? Text in titles etc should be ignored? (And what is "*regular*" HTML?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor HTML 4 will be "regular" HTML (since HTML5 has to still work dominating the world!) although thst reslly wouldn't affect the crawling that much. The paragraph, preformatted text, and header will be counted as visible text.

Comment: "*HTML 4*" still isn't very precise. Can answers require input to be conforming HTML 4.01 Strict?

Comment: @PeterTaylor ok.

Comment: This sandbox post has had little activity in a while and little positive reception from the community. Please improve / edit it or delete it to help us [clean up the sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12792)

Answer (score -5):

## Calculate Hello World!

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded)

Your goal is to calculate the simple string "hello world" or any other variant.

### Rules

- You may not use the characters in this set (inside your code): `hHeElLoOwW rRdD!`, in **any form** (character codes, hex codes, etc. not allowed) [only applies for direct use].
- Your program may not take any input from any source.
- Your program may only print `hello world` or any other variant to standard output (for your language). Again, it may **not print anything else**.
- Standard loopholes apply (to clarify, they are **not forbidden**).
- This challenge is underhanded.
- Your program may not use any built-in string of printable characters (for example, `string.printable` in Python).
- I recommend you be creative.

Remember, this is [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)! Have fun!

Comment: This is a trivial variant on stuff which has been done to death. It's also a [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/194) question with [obvious loopholes](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22hello%20world%22Ff%5E&input=%22\(%25%2C%2C%2F%607%2F2%2C%24%2264f%5E).

Comment: @Peter, I wrote this for creativity. I wanted to see the community's creative answers.

Comment: This is not creative even remotely. I would even go as far as saying this is a duplicate of antoher challenge

Comment: [Underhanded contests are off topic by community consensus.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/12012)

Answer (score -5):

**Letter Grade Challenge**

Create a program that allows the user to input an `int` between 1 and 100, then grades that number based on standard US letter grades, printing the grade character as a result. Please use Java for this challenge, and like usual code golf challenges, the smallest answer (bytes) wins.
For example, if input is `90`, then you display `A`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and thank you for sandboxing. Please include the exact cut-off points. Is the input an integer or a floating point? Are the extremes included or excluded. We generally frown on language-specific challenges. Do you have any particular reason for restricting answers to Java?

Comment: Don't restrict which languages you can use. All it does is keep people who don't know Java from answering your past. Also, you should include the definition of the letter grade scale in your challenge, rather than along readers to look it up.

Comment: You don't need to include the clause about multiple files. At PPCG, we include all necessary code in the byte-count.

Comment: What are "*standard US letter grades*"?

Comment: 90-100: A;

89-80: B;

79-70: C;

69-60: D;

59-0: F

Comment: @Pavel Sorry about that. I saw a few people posting python only challenges a while back, so I assumed specific languages are the norm.

Comment: @OCDkirby >_> Because people did that more often "A while back" doesn't mean it's still the norm, just look at the questions on the main page

Comment: That's several years back. What was on-topic several years back can be off-topic now. Remember to see the timestamp. /// [so] has the same problem: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094889/how-to-use-rapidshare-api-to-get-account-details) (first revision). Now the title is not valid.

Comment: Please [edit] necessary information into the post. / Some example I/O please?

Comment: [Probable dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49876/76162)

Comment: @JoKing They use different letter grades. There is no 'E' in this grading system, and the number value requirements are different.

Comment: @OCDkirby But still, if the algorthm on the other question can be adapted for this question with small modification, it's considered a dupe.

Comment: @user202729 Is editing every condition in an `if` statement and removing one condition considered a "small modification"?

Answer (score -5):

## Shortest Possible 240 Sided Die Program: Using No Constant Greater than 6

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Have you ever played Yahtzee with a 240-sided die? No, probably not. Anyway, I came up with the idea of a 240-sided die program, but to make it hard, you cannot use a constant with an absolute value greater than 6. For example, `randInt(1,240)` wouldn't work. The chances of any number 1-240 must be completely equal, and using expressions that represent numbers with an absolute value larger than 240 is not allowed. For example, `randInt(1,4*6*2*5)` is against the rules, since `4*6*2*5` evaluates to 240. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) prohibited, and you're code golfing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76678/discussion-on-answer-by-redwolf10105-sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Answer (score -5):

I recently made a language called `bit`, and your challenge is to create a valid program that takes 2 numbers from STDIN, and outputs the sum of them.
You may assume the numbers are no more than 5 digits, and your output doesn't need to be more than 5 digits long

## Bit Specification

You can find the specification and an interpreter at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/FireCubez/bit)

Comment: Do you have a reference interpreter or compiler? How can we test a solution?

Comment: @qwr I do, in Java, should I add it to the question?

Comment: Yes it's very helpful

Comment: @qwr Actually how am I going to do that, the file isn't online anywhere

Comment: You may just paste the java code in your question, or even better link a TIO script (https://tio.run/#java-openjdk) so people can run it online

Comment: @qwr It's much more than 1k lines of code, and multiple classes, however I have a GitHub now, added to question

Comment: Ok that suggests to me the problem may be too long. Others may feel differently

Comment: @qwr Not really, Java code tends to be long, there's no problem in that

Comment: Well the meta here is for challenges that don't feel arbitrary, and to me this is leaning towards an arbitrary list of commands for your own personal language.

Comment: @qwr So you think the idea is bad?

Comment: I wouldn't call it bad, which is a pretty broad term, but challenges that are easy to understand and conceptualize are generally better received and get more responses (if that is what you want)

Comment: Unrelated: Github is generally for hosting source code and packages/binaries like .jar (these can be included in [releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/))

Comment: If you posted this it would likely get closed as a dupe of [Add two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84260/76162). Instead of posting this, I'd recommend just submitting solutions in Bit yourself and seeing if anyone else is interested

Answer (score -5):

## Count up to **N** without math or inbuilds

#### Idea:

The challenge is the following: count from 0 up to **N** without using mathematical operations or other (counting, list or whatever) inbuilds.
You handle the incoming number **N** as a string on which you can't apply mathematical operations like addition or substraction for example. Also don't use list things like print [0..**N**] or something other inbuilt of your language. Counting inside arrays, for example at index x+1 or something like that to get position after another is allowed. But you must not apply any (mathematical) operations on the numbers between 0 and **N** itself.

Think that you are like a small child and don't know anything about maths. You only know:
after 0 comes 1, after 1 comes 2 ... after 8 comes 9 and after 9 comes 0 and you have to "increment" the number in front of it.

#### Examples:

- So after the number 9 (with leading, but not outwritten zero) comes, you write zero and place the number 1 in front of it for 10.
- For 19 you write 0 and "increment" the number in front to the next one, making it 20.
- For 399 you do: last 9 goes to zero, 9 in front goes to 0 too and the  3 goes to 4, making it 400.

#### Task:

Write a function or program which takes **N** via the way you want to as its input. 
Output the numbers from 0 up to **N** (element after element or once as a list)

Important: use a seperator as 01234567891011 will become unreadable with larger numbers

#### Test Case:

Taking a string of seperated numbers and your seperator, you can check your answer [here](https://tio.run/##fVFNT8MwDD23v8Lk1KlmLGXjQ6PigMQv4AYcsjQtQSWZknQSQvvtw2krQNPKIYrznv2eHb@LnfDS6W04N7ZSh4sLCBZ2otWVCAp8cNo06aftnLdd2Hahscq/KaegBMbWA7NtdfCfHxvbRhQITqOO61QqSrZAjgVe4hJXeIXXeIO3yAnkyAvkl8iXyFfIr5BfI79BfovFAgtOKhsqpktOaYxGtWi9SquS9TkEKgoL0i5IvFgSUP8qjPVsfag7I4O2BmprM212wmE/SVBuBl@QJoSAcI5m6tl5z2Y/OeshQxK/GGNLcRyb@kpq6yCLoO4T6LqLavNWmSa80TvPySZNEl1DRsSzfoWzEuQAJk6FzplhNlJP9nRknlO4J/GRHbz2B2mNt62at7bJGP2I9hAXA8PKQFrnlAz3jHr@mxoHP7VaPNrqDHJgLyaWp8dWT9QCPAiv/Cl1gQzZ7ASxmSJkT/xj@Bh/ZNqxmhJWU0Q9Eodv).

**Ah, and also don't forget that this is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes will win. Also, all standard loophole rules and so on apply (you should know from all the other challenges!)**

---

## Sandbox

I hope this challenge has never been here, I did not found it while searching trough the already asked challenges (maybe I did not found it because I did not knew the correct english words to search for because english is not my first language). Thank you already in advance for helping to improve this challenge.

#### Tags:

counting, code-golf

Comment: Thank you for putting your first challenge into the Sandbox! Know that do-X-without-Y [are difficult to get right], and generally discouraged for those that do not have a lot of challenge writing experience. If all built-in language features are prohibited, then the challenge is obviously impossible, and if not, how will you decide what is and what isn't allowed for all languages. Please do not make assumptions about language features — there are odd languages out there.

Comment: @Adám  I see what you mean with built ins, but dont know how to specify it in other terms. i mean things like inbuild methods that automatically output from [0..N] wihtout doing anything as a programmer. What I want to see, is the numbers from 0 to N, each seen as a string with no mathematical operations on it. The counting should happen in a way of the "algorithm" of how small children (with no knowledge about mathematics) count, pattern matching stlye. A child sees the 1, takes the next known value 2 and that it is.,Is it understandable what I mean?

Comment: Sure it is clear what you *want*, but challenges must be unambiguous, and it must be possible to objectively judge if an answer is allowed or not.

Comment: Maybe instead you rephrase the challenge as: *Given a list of digits, increment the number that they represent in base-10.* This way, you can require that solutions handle inputs that are way too wide for normal integer representations. Of course, some languages have "infinite-precision" integers, but such solutions then just don't deserve upvotes for cleverness.

Comment: @Adám - or is it possible to write it like: "'count' from 0 to N, but not by interpreting 0 to N as numbers, they are strings. you are a small child, you know nothing about arithmetics and you only know the word representations of numbers and what number comes after another by following rules. [...]". or does this still opens the possibility to use the numbers as integers for example?

Comment: That doesn't help, we'll just evaluate the string, find the range, then stringify the numbers. Also, if you prohibit arithmetic, how are we to add digits? With a lookup table?

Comment: Yeah that is what I want to achieve. The one solving the task needs to lookup what number comes after the one he is looking at (without doing calculus on the number itself).
something like having a string all="01234567890" and with that you search for s in all and look at the next symbol (next symbol can be fetched with +1, this is allowed, but you are not allowed to add +1 to s directly). e.g. you have the number 5, you lookup the next number in all, which is 6, and so on.
the "next" operation is something the child does intuitive, without knowing that this is an mathematical operation.

Comment: on top of that, there is one special case when going from most significant position of the number beeing a 9 to a 0 and adding a new 1 as most significant position. (9->10, 99->100, 999->1000 and so on ...). is that too simple? guess it can be interesting what kind of solution people come up on the lookup thing and special case optimization - @Adám

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96595/discussion-between-adam-and-pixma140).

Answer (score -5):

## [[semantic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic-code-golf) new contest type proposal]

Given a phrase, express it, or something with the same meaning, in as few syllables as possible. Entries may be in any officially recognised or well-known language that is not a programming language (e.g. you can use Chinese or English, but not MyOwnSpokenLanguage or Python). Shortest number of syllables wins!

Comment: This is *Code Golf* not *Language Golf*

Comment: @Seggan-OnStrike *Code Golf* also isn’t *[tag:proof-golf]*

Comment: Point should be clear aim

Comment: @l4m2 I don't understand what you're saying, please elaborate.

Answer (score -5):

### Thoughts on a scoring system that levels the playing field between golfing languages and common languages.

Divide the byte length of a program by a "popularity" metric e.g.

- Wikipedia page views in the last 30 days (or esolangs.org)
- Wikipedia edits
- questions on Stack Overflow tagged with that language

Idea would be to encourage golfing in languages used day to day rather than the languages written purely for the purpose of golfing.

#### Pros

- Code Golf questions often reach the "Hot network questions" sidebar but then new/unfamiliar users are met with incomprehensible code, this could reduce that
- encourage new users to attempt an answer
- whilst users are encouraged to compete with others in the same language, the overall winner normally gets the accepted answer, this could help that

#### Cons

- this is Code Golf, so least bytes is the goal!
- people have put immense effort into creating the golfing languages and that shouldn't be punished
- finding/creating a "good" popularity metric is probably going to be a lot of work

### Case studies

Rescoring [Covfefify a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123685/covfefify-a-string) by dividing the length by * wikipedia (or eslangs.org if no wiki page) number of edits * 1000. Then rounded down.

Lang - OG score - Edits - New score

Jelly - 57 - 9 - 6333

JavaScript - 103 - 7695 - 13

Jelly - 39 - 9 - 4333

C - 175 - 8659 - 20

CJam - 56 - 9 - 6222

Perl 5 (Perl) - 71 - 4133 - 17

PHP - 121 - 11287 - 10

Pyth - 54 - 22 - 2454

Python 3 (Python) - 139 - 8850 - 15

Java 8 (Java) - 222 - 8978 - 24

Haskell - 136 - 2089 - 65

Ruby - 90 - 2936 - 30

##### Results in a HTML table

```html
<google-sheets-html-origin style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; border: none;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <th>Lang</th>
      <th>OG score</th>
      <th>Edits</th>
      <th>New score</th>
      <th>Log(edits) score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead><colgroup><col width="100"><col width="100"><col width="100"><col width="100"><col width="100"></colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Jelly&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Jelly</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:57}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">57</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">9</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:6333.333333333333}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">6333</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:59.733243317247464}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">59.73324332</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;JavaScript&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">JavaScript</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:103}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">103</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:7695}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">7695</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:13.385315139701104}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">13</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:26.50398111914659}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">26.50398112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Jelly&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Jelly</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:39}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">39</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">9</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:4333.333333333333}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">4333</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:40.870113848643}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">40.87011385</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;C&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">C</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:175}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">175</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:8659}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">8659</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:20.21018593371059}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">20</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:44.44480858549206}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">44.44480859</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;CJam&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">CJam</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:56}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">56</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">9</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:6222.222222222223}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">6222</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:58.68529168010277}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">58.68529168</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Perl 5 (Perl)&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Perl 5 (Perl)</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:71}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">71</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:4133}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">4133</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:17.17880474231793}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">17</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:19.633514701742165}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">19.6335147</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;PHP&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">PHP</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:121}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">121</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:11287}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">11287</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:10.720297687605209}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">11</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:29.857533728767567}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">29.85753373</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Pyth&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Pyth</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:54}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">54</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:22}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">22</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:2454.5454545454545}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">2455</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:40.22578042776074}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">40.22578043</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Python 3 (Python)&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Python 3 (Python)</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:139}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">139</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:8850}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">8850</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:15.706214689265536}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">16</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:35.21712638535709}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">35.21712639</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Java 8 (Java)&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Java 8 (Java)</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:222}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">222</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:8978}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">8978</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:24.72711071508131}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">25</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:56.157327114648886}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">56.15732711</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Haskell&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Haskell</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:136}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">136</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:2089}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">2089</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:65.10292005744375}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">65</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:40.96461499473064}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">40.96461499</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Ruby&quot;}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom;">Ruby</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:90}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">90</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:2936}" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">2936</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:30.653950953678475}" data-sheets-numberformat="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:1}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-2]/R[0]C[-1]*1000" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">31</td>
      <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:25.953382726479024}" data-sheets-formula="=R[0]C[-3]/LOG(R[0]C[-2])" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 3px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">25.95338273</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></google-sheets-html-origin>
```

Just using the number of edits makes the golfing languages irrelevant. The log(edits) brings everything into quite a nice grouping.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not a challenge idea, so it should be a standalone meta question instead of a sandbox post

Answer (score -5):

## Obfuscated bananas

---

In this challenge, your task is to print the string `banana`, case insensitive, to STDOUT (or an acceptable alternative) in the most obfuscated way.

> +1 VTC! No objective winning criterion!

Wrong! ***I now have an objective winning criterion!***

---

Let the reporter edit distance of \$a\$ and \$b\$ be the lowest number of operations on \$a\$ required to have a consecutive subset of \$a\$ equal to \$b\$. For the reporter distance, you can only use these operations:

- Add a character
- Remove a character
- Change a character
- Swap the positions of two characters

---

Your score is the reporter distance of your source code and `banana`, case insensitive, with a higher score being better.

---

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded)

---

### Meta

- Duplicate?
- Unclear?
- More tags?
- Anything else?

Comment: There will probably be a lot of codes with score 6, by avoiding `b`, `a` and `n` completely. Perhaps add some component of the code length, although that might make it just "print `banana` without `b`, `a`, `n`".

Answer (score -6):

## Smallest code to import in G++

Given some head files that need to import, return the shortest code to do so.

1. You are allowed to access `include/`
2. You should consider both `#include <xxx>` and `#include "xxx"`(used in e.g. `backward/hash_set #include "backward_warning.h"`), but not `#import` (std don't use `#import`)

Sample input `['string']`

Sample output `#import<map>`

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150895/busy-beaver)

1. What more assumption necessary? (`#if` don't effect imported heads?)
2. Time limit necessary?

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) [c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: I don't understand what is the challenge.

Comment: I don't think [tag:tips] questions have to go through the sandbox

Comment: @user202729 I do. C++ header files may include other header files. It's mostly implementation-specific. This person's <map> header happens to include <string> so if you want <string> it's shorter to include <map> instead.

Comment: @user253751 ... that comment was made two years ago. I don't remember what it's about now.

Answer (score -6):

Merge two code in two languages into a polyglot.

E.g. If you choose C & Python 3, you can merge

```
main(){puts("a");}
```

and

```
print(6)
```

into

```
#define print(x) main(){puts("a");}
print(6)
```

[popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) (for it's hard to have a score on language difficulty, optimizy, etc.)

Comment: This is way too broad as it is currently written. "Do X Creatively" is out of scope, even for popularity-contests.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork It seems not a creatively challenge? though I don't vote it that high either

Answer (score -10):

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

## Delete or a file disapear as fast as possible!

Requirements to participate:

- have a HDD hard drive, witch you will use to compete
- Use Windows (version 7 or more recent) for this challenge.

Assume that you already know the file path. no input needed.

You can use any language you want for this challenge, but you will need to explain the logic in your code.

You will delete a 2GB file.

### How do you win?

You win this challenge by creating a piece of code that can delete a file in the OS as fast as possible, the winner is the one with less time to delete a file.

Comment: This is a) too wide open to interpretation; b) far more dependent on the hardware than on the software.

Comment: so what? I say in the begining what the requirements to participate are, only the ones that match the requirements can participate, else the results will be so diferent i cant even evaluate @PeterTaylor

Comment: And what do you mean "wide open to interpretation?" @PeterTaylor

Comment: What does it mean to "*make a file disappear*"? If I unmount the disk, does that count? How about if I format the index block? Change the permissions so that I can no longer see it? Rename it? Toggle the disk header so that it seems to be a different filesystem and won't mount? Is `rm` acceptable, or do I need to `shred`? Can I insist on a filesystem of my choice (probably FAT)?

Answer (score -10):

## Worst language Ever

Let's find out the worst language.

Make a program that does anything that is shortest.

The worst language would be the longest of all.

I'll go with C first.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 15 bytes

```c
f(){puts("1");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oLSkWEPJUEnTuvZ/bmJmHlAIKAzkAAA)

It prints 1.

It does print something and it is the shortest code.

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 8 bytes

```swift
print(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/oCgzr0TDSPP/fwA)

It prints 2. It does print something that is shortest.

Comment: How would you define "does anything"?

Comment: Also it's nontrivial to verify whether a program is the shortest possible, unless you tried all programs shorter than that.

Comment: Print anything except nothing. You can have an input

Comment: So this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge which ask users to output anything? Isn't this too broad? I will let others to judge...

Comment: Doing all of that, we can find the worst language.

Answer (score -12):

## Divisibility by 4

Your job is to write a program that checks divisibility of an integer by 4.

**Restrictions:**

You can't use:

- modulo
- binary shift/rotates
- Divisions

You must instead do it like a **HUMAN DOES** by checking the last 2 digits and output a truthy value when is divisible and a falsey when not.

Non-printable characters; golfing-dedicated, whitespace and esoteric languages are forbidden.

The winner will be the code that has less characters, where white space doesn't count (tabs, spaces and newlines).

Comment: [Even humans have a variety of different ways of doing division](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34641091#34641091) [Also forbids esolangs, golfing langs, unprintables, and whitespace.
Not the language. Just whitespace.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34641100#34641100)

Comment: People never like when they can't use their favorite language for a challenge.  I would seriously recommend removing the language restriction as it not only is it next to impossible to reliably enforce (you have been already linked several meta discussions so I'll leave that out) but it is most importantly not very fun for the people involved.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent There are a number of problems here, which it is useful to point out, but I think "I hate this challenge" is unnecessary.

Comment: Can I forbid only whitespace languages, as they would automatically win by my measures?

Comment: Are we allowed to check / use the other digits, too or just the last two digits? Does looping through all digits to reach the last two digits count as "checking / looking at / using"?

Comment: I think that you could because it is objective.  But the much better alternative would be to simply count whitespace.  Why do you want to not count whitespace.

Comment: @nimi: One more time I tell you that is absolutely not necessary. You can, but that will for sure increase your non-whitespace char count!

Comment: @WheatWizard: I want to measure it in terms of "Visual Overload". Whitepace does not have any visual load and when exists even alleviates the "visual overload" of characters that have it!

Comment: Since the discussion has already grown quite long I have created a room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51421/discussion-for-sergiols-divisibilty-by-4-challenge

Comment: *Implements question using whitespace.*

Answer (score -14):

## Write the worst Hello World program you can [popularity-contest] [super rough]

Who needs conventions? Write the most terrible Hello World program you can think of. Inefficiency, spaghetti code, you name it. Add a few gotos here and there to spice it up. Write code that has gone against everything you've ever been taught.

Be creative. This isn't about obfuscation: it's about bad code quality. Try making up your own ways of writing inefficient or unadaptable code. Have fun!

Comment: VTC because of no winning criterion, objective or not.  Needs some work.

Comment: I suggest a [tag:code-bowling] criterion, but this is still _way_ too broad.

Comment: As I said, it's super rough and needs a lot of work.

Comment: This is essentially code trolling, which was deemed off topic a few years ago.